# Add a language to a polyglot

Tags: polyglot, answer-chaining

This is an [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge in which each answer builds on the previous answer. I recommend sorting the thread by "oldest" in order to be sure about the order in which the posts are made.

> **Note**: This has become quite a long-lasting challenge, and posting new answers is fairly difficult. As such, there's now a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development) available for this challenge, in case you want advice on a particular part of a potential answer, have ideas for languages that could be added, or the like. Feel free to drop in if you have anything to ask or say!

## The task

The *n*th program to be submitted must run in *n* different languages; specifically, all the languages added in previous programs to be submitted, plus one more. The program must output 1 when run in the first language used in answers to this question, 2 when run in the second language, and so on. For example, the first answer could print 1 when run in Python 3, and the second answer could output 1 when run in Python 3 and 2 when run in JavaScript; in this case, the third answer would have to output 1 when run in Python 3, 2 when run in JavaScript, and 3 when run in some other language.

## Additional rules

- Your program must run without erroring out or crashing. Warnings (and other stderr output) are acceptable, but the program must exit normally (e.g. by running off the end of the program, or via a command such as `exit` that performs normal program termination).
- The output must be only the integer, but trailing newlines are OK. Other unavoidable stdout output is also allowed. Examples: [interpreter name and version](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOoUIvKY1LP7@gRD8pNa00Lz1VPykzD8QGy/z/r6SYklOUH66gk5@Tk@qhZGelrBPvAAA) in Befunge-93,
  [space after printed string](https://tio.run/##q0otyKgs@v@/oCgzr0TB0Nz0/38A) in Zephyr. Some languages provide two methods of printing – with and without
  trailing space; in this case method without trailing space must be used.
- Each answer must be no more than 20% or 20 bytes (whichever is larger) longer than the previous answer. (This is to prevent the use of languages like Lenguage spamming up the thread, and to encourage at least a minor amount of golfing.)
- Using different versions of the same language is allowed (although obviously they'll have to print different numbers, so you'll need to fit a version check into the polyglot). However, you may not use a language feature that returns the language's version number. Repeating the exact same language is, obviously, impossible (as the program would have to deterministically print one of two different numbers).
- Tricks like excessive comment abuse, despite being banned in some polyglot competitions, are just fine here.
- You don't have to use the previous answers as a guide to writing your own (you can rewrite the whole program if you like, as long as it complies with the spec); however, basing your answer mostly on a previous answer is allowed and probably the easiest way to make a solution.
- You cannot submit two answers in a row. Let someone else post in between. This rule applies until victory condition is met.
- As this challenge requires other competitors to post in the same languages you are, you can only use languages with a [free implementation](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7822/62131) (much as though this were a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) contest).
- In the case where a language has more than one interpreter, you can pick any interpreter for any given language so long as all programs which are meant to run successfully in that language do so in that interpreter. (In other words, if a program works in more than one interpreter, future posts can pick either of those interpreters, rather than a post "locking in" a particular choice of interpreter for a language.)
- If some interpreter gets updated and the program no longer works in the newer version then new answers can either stick to the old version or fix the program to work in the new version.
- This challenge now uses the [new PPCG rules about language choice](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges?cb=1): you can use a language, or a language interpreter, even if it's newer than the question. However, you may not use a language/interpreter that's newer than the question if a) the language was designed for the purpose of polyglotting or b) the language was inspired by this question. (So newly designed practical programming languages are almost certainly going to be OK, as are unrelated esolangs, but things like [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree), which was inspired by this question, are banned.) Note that this doesn't change the validity of languages designed for polyglotting that are older than this question.
- Note that the victory condition (see below) is designed so that breaking the chain (i.e. making it impossible for anyone else to answer after you via the use of a language that is hard to polyglot with further languages) will disqualify you from winning. The aim is to keep going as long as we can, and if you want to win, you'll have to respect that.

## Answer format

As all the answers depend on each other, having a consistent answer format is going to be helpful. I recommend formatting your answer something like this (this is an example for the second link in the chain):

> ## 2. JavaScript, 40 bytes
>
> ```
> (program goes here)
> ```
>
> This program prints **1** in Python 3, and **2** in JavaScript.
>
> (if you want to explain the program, the polyglotting techniques, etc., place them here)

## Victory condition

Once there have been no new answers for 14 days, the winner will be whoever posted the *second* newest answer, i.e. the largest polyglot that's been proven not to have broken the chain. Extending the chain after that is still very welcome, though!

The winner is [Chance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63156), see [answer 194 (TemplAt)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163497).

## Language list

```js
// This snippet is based on the snippet from hello world thread https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world
// It was tested only in Google Chrome

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, number) => (typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match) );
  };
}

var QUESTION_ID = 102370; // from the question url
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

var answers = [], answer_page = 1;

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      if (data.has_more) { $('#status').text($('#status').text() + '.'); getAnswers(); }
      else process();
    },
    // [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states that `error` handler is not called for cross-domain JSONP requests, 
    // but it works here, probably because api.stackexchange.com and codegolf.stackexchange.com are on the same domain.
    error:  function (a,b,c) { 
      $('#status').text( "Failed to load answers: " + b + " " + c );
      console.log( b + " " + c );
    },
  });
}

getAnswers();

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290442/html-input-type-text-onchange-event-not-working/39834997#39834997
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', onSearchInput);

function onSearchInput(e)
{
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var str = e.srcElement.value.toLowerCase();
    var num_results = 0;

    if(str == "") // optimization for empty input
    {
        // show all rows
        for(var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
        {
            row.className = "";
            num_results++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
        {
            var hidden = row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) == -1;
            if(!hidden) num_results++;
            row.className = hidden ? "hidden" : "";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerText = "Results: " + num_results;
}


/* Function ParseHeader() extracts answer number, language name and size of polyglot from answer header.
   Argument: `header` - answer header string without markup, eg. "1. Python 3 (8 bytes)" or "59. Tcl, 1324 bytes".
   Retval:  object, eg. {num: 1, language: "Python 3", size: 8} or 
            null if header has wrong format
  
   There are two formats of header, new one with comma and old one with parens.
   Parsing new format only with regexp is hard because:
   - language name may contain commas,                                 eg. "51. Assembly (x64, Linux, AS), 1086 bytes"
   - there may be several sizes, of which the last one should be used, eg. "210. Haskell without MonomorphismRestriction, 10035 9977 bytes"

   There are only several answers with old format header: 1-5, 7, 12-17, 21. All of them have single size and don't have parens in language name,
   so they can be parsed with simple regexp.
   
   Algorithm: Find commas. If there are no commas parse it as old format. Otherwise parse it as new format.
   New format parsing: Let everything after last comma be `sizes`. Check if `sizes` ends with the word "bytes". If not, set size to 0.
   Take the word before "bytes" and convert it to number. Parse the rest of the header (before last comma) with regexp.
*/
function ParseHeader(header)
{
  var a = header.split(',');
  if(a.length > 1) // current format: Number "." Language "," Size+ "bytes"
  {
    // filter(s=>s) removes empty strings from array (handle multiple consecutive spaces)
    var sizes = a[a.length-1].split(" ").filter(s=>s); // " 123 100  bytes " -> ["123", "100", "bytes"]
    var size;
    if(sizes.length < 2 || sizes[sizes.length-1] != "bytes") size = 0;
    else size = +sizes[sizes.length-2];

    a.splice(a.length-1,1); // remove last element
    var match = a.join(',').match(/(\d*)\.(.*)/);
    if (!match) return null;
    return{
            num: +match[1],
            language: match[2].trim(),
            size: size,
          };
  }
  else // old format: Number "." Language "(" Size "bytes" ")"
  {
    var format = /(\d*)\.([^(]*)\((\d*)\s*bytes\)/;
    var match = header.match(format);
    if (!match) return null;
    return{
            num: +match[1],
            language: match[2].trim(),
            size: +match[3]
          };
  }
}

// 1533246057 (number of seconds since UTC 00:00 1 Jan 1970) -> "Aug 2 '18"
// other useful Date functions: toUTCString, getUTCDate, getUTCMonth, getUTCFullYear
function FormatDate(n)
{
  var date = new Date(n*1000); // takes milliseconds
  var md = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {timeZone:"UTC", day:"numeric", month:"short"});
  var y  = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {timeZone:"UTC", year:"2-digit"});
  return md + " '" + y;
}


var processed = []; // processed answers, it's called `valid` in original snippet

function ProcessAnswer(a)
{
  var body = a.body, header;

  //
  // Extract header from answer body.
  // Try find <h1> header (markdown #). If not found try find <h2> (markdown ##).
  // Extracted header contains only text, all markup is stripped.
  // For 99 language markup is later readded to language name because markup is essential for it.
  //
  var el = document.createElement('html'); // dummy element used for finding header
  el.innerHTML = body;
  var headers = el.getElementsByTagName('h1');
  if(headers.length != 0) header = headers[0].innerText;
  else {
    headers = el.getElementsByTagName('h2');
    if(headers.length != 0) header = headers[0].innerText;
    else { console.log(body); return; } // error: <h1> and <h2> not found
  }

  var info = ParseHeader(header)
  if(!info) { console.log(body); return; } // error: unrecognised header format

  if(info.num == 99 && info.language == "99") info.language = "<i>99</i>";

  processed.push({
    num:         info.num,
    language:    info.language,
    size:        info.size,
    answer_link:   a.share_link,
    user:          a.owner.display_name,
    user_link:     a.owner.link,         // `undefined` if user was deleted
    creation_date: a.creation_date,      // unix epoch (number of seconds since UTC 00:00 1 Jan 1970)
  });
}

function process()
{
  $('#status').remove();

  answers.forEach(ProcessAnswer); // answers -> processed
  
  processed.sort( (a,b)=>(a.num-b.num) ); // sort by answer number, ascending

  processed.forEach(function (a) {
    
    var date = FormatDate(a.creation_date);

    var user = a.user_link ? ('<a href="'+a.user_link+'">'+a.user+'</a>') : a.user; // redundant code, currently the only deleted user is ais523
    if(user == "user62131") user = '<a href="https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/246227/ais523">ais523</a>';

    var style = (a.num == 194) ? "background: #ccf" : ""; // 194 is winner answer

    var row = "<tr style='{0}'><td>{1}</td> <td><a href='{2}'>{3}</a></td> <td>{4}</td> <td>{5}</td> <td>{6}</td></tr>"
              .format(style, a.num, a.answer_link, a.language, a.size, user, date);

    $('#answers').append( row );
  });
}
```

```css
a {text-decoration:none}
a:visited {color:#00e}

table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
td, th { padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; white-space: nowrap; }
tr:hover { background-color: #ff9; }
td:first-child  { text-align:center; } /* # */
td:nth-child(4) { font-style:italic; } /* author */
td:nth-child(5) { text-align:right;  } /* date */

p { margin: 8px 0px }
.hidden { display: none } /* search hides rows */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span>Search: </span><input autofocus> &nbsp;<span id="results"></span>
</p>
<table class="answer-list">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>#</th> <th>Language</th> <th>Size (bytes)</th> <th>Author</th> <th>Date</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="answers">
  
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="status">Loading answers...</div>
```

Comment: For people who can see deleted posts: the Sandbox post was [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10784/62131).

Comment: How should permalinks be updated? Should the newest answer contain permalinks of all the previous languages?

Comment: There's no need to copy the previous program, although of course you can use it as a guide; redoing the program from scratch is likely to take longer! There's no need to permalink to answers; sorting by oldest will show all the answers in order already.

Comment: @ais523 I think what was meant was that should new answers contain try it links with the new code?

Comment: In hindsight there could have been a requirement to check validity of answers before new answers can be posted, e.g. in [meta regex golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41462/a-different-kind-of-meta-regex-golf).

Comment: Is it ok if the language does not have an online interpreter, but has one on github (but has to be downloaded)?

Comment: As PPCG rules require allowing as many languages to compete as reasonably possible, I don't think it can be fair to *require* there to be an online way to test the program (and the post as currently written doesn't), although you must of course give people some way to test. Perhaps you could try to persuade one of the online language hosts to add the language you're thinking of, though, to make things easier?

Comment: @ais523 I have already written an online interpreter (based on the GH code) for haystack, but I will ask someone to add the language on TIO, thanks!

Comment: I think we need a script that takes a hex dump of the code and automatically runs it in all the languages...

Comment: Is it okay to exit with a non-zero error code that is not crashing, e.g. Befunge-98's `q` command?

Comment: @Sp3000: Yes. Intentionally reporting failed execution is distinct from a crash.

Comment: This is the [Versatile integer printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65641/31516) posted as a different type of challenge. (Inspiration?) The final answer (currently) would score `0.0127`, only beaten by Sp3000's 30 language submission... :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin I actually just added a snippet to my [last answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108402/39056) that shows the scores for all the answers if they'd been submitted for that challenge

Comment: This challenge is perfectly described by its tags: [polyglot] [answer-chaining].

Comment: Can we use languages that were "created" (pushed to GitHub) barely a month after the challenge?

Comment: @MDXF: Unfortunately no. PPCG rules are fairly frustrating for a challenge like this, but if you start violating them, you end up in a subjective minefield of what is and isn't legal.

Comment: @ais523 that's disappointing. I was going to add ;# cause it's quite easy

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I really doubt it would be as easy as you think. There are quite a few `#`'s in the code, and it wouldn't be possible to just add random `;`'s.

Comment: @MDXF it's probably the easiest language of all of them to add given that it was designed for polyglot Kolmogorov complexity challenges (# and ; are common comment symbols

Comment: @StewieGriffin it is now under `0.003` :)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yeah, except there are already about 300 instances of `#` in the code.

Comment: This challenge has been linked from the Wikipedia article on Polyglots.

Comment: Are we going to award the accepted answer to anyone else than stasoid and potato44? Because they did most of the answers?

Comment: @Michthan The accepted answer would have gone to the winner, which in this case is the second newest answer when 14 days have passed since the most recent answer. But because ais523 is no longer a member of PPCG no answer will get accepted as he isn't here to do so.

Comment: For authors of similar challenges (in which bigger thing is built based on previous answers): please, don't prohibit a user from adding several answers in a row. This rule is harmful. It gave me a LOT of trouble, I had to wait for weeks, sometimes for months to add an answer. That was absolutely agonizing.
This rule together with winning condition artificially creates competition for inherently collaborative challenge. Note that having winning condition is not obligatory - e.g. [hello world challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422) explicitly does not have one.

Comment: @stasoid It's code-golf.

Comment: @stasoid A compromise might be something like: You cannot post two answers in a row within less than 7 days. That means you can get two answers in a row only once things start slowing seriously down.

Comment: At long last, we made it to Pi.

Answer (score 88):

> Note: If you see this first, you might want to [sort by oldest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot?answertab=createdasc)

### 17. Julia (128 bytes)

```
#v`16 "<" 6/b0\ .q@#;n4"14""
#>3N9@15o|R"12"*^
#=|
print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62);# =#;print(17)
#gg99ddi2` |1|1+6
```

There are two ESCs on the last line, one before the first `g` and one after the `2`. This could be golfed more, but things got messy no thanks to V and Pyth.

Prints 1 in Python 3, 2 in V, 3 in Minkolang, 4 in ><>, 5 in Python 2, 6 in SMBF, 7 in Japt, 8 in Retina, 9 in Perl, 10 in Befunge-93, 11 in Befunge-98, 12 in Fission, 13 in Ruby, 14 in Turtléd, 15 in Haystack, 16 in Pyth and [**17 in Julia**](https://tio.run/#8hWKF).

---

Hints:

- The start of the fourth line is Python 2/3, Perl, Ruby. The end is Julia, thanks to `#=` multiline comments (note that Julia doesn't have `and/or`).
- V is `<ESC>gg99ddi2<ESC>`, which is definitely golfable but V is annoying to test on *Try it online!* since the interpreter is fairly slow.
- Minkolang and Haystack go down at the first `v`. Befunge-93 and -98 don't, and depend on a `b`.
- Retina counts the number of spaces and 1s in the fourth line, and V hides in the config for Retina (i.e. before the backtick).
- Per @ETHproduction's hint, Japt uses backticks to hide the majority of the code in a string.
- Fission is `R"12"*`.
- SMBF has been golfed to `<.` in the first line, plus the final `6`.

Comment: Where has everyone else's code gone though

Comment: 159 bytes to 128 bytes? Wow, that's some excellent golfing!

Comment: Nice, 2^7 bytes

Comment: I was working on a 99 version for 17, I got it within 2 bytes of the rules and then you come in with this huge improvement! I'm never going to get 99 into this aha.

Comment: If you're going for golfing, the V section could be shortened to `<esc>HcL2<esc>`. Of course, I don't know if this would mess with the other languages or not.

Comment: Wow... incredible! We're going to have to write up a new explanation for every language when all's said and done ;-)

Comment: @mbomb007 ah fair enough, I had assumed it had to build on the others

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre "You don't have to use the previous answers as a guide to writing your own (you can rewrite the whole program if you like, as long as it complies with the spec)"

Comment: amazing, 101 lang))

Answer (score 61):

## 50. bash, 1024 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)" 3//v\D(@;'[af2.qc]GkGGZ'#)"14";n4
#/*` "[!PPP(22)SP(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@ ␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=<xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDOiiipsddsdoh@O6O4/]>+.-- -. >][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[/v/v(/0l0v01k1kx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)  0046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
'\';echo 50;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.\."12"__*'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#ssseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp/*/
#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(  )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*'``
<>{# }//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#< >"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\
#ss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#ss*///nd^_^_Z222999"26
```

Want to learn more? Try the [polygot chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)!

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpJc9tIlj43/kJd0iDLBEgCIKnFCwlasi3XqDZrLNkVYZKWQDBJwsJWWCRKMhVznYk59L0vc@z/0df5Ff1Har6XCS7aXFWHjhg6CCYyX749X7735N9K9GEHkX8x8aOMZTzN2CjxznhispcXbMfx0q3WhqIIqCQa5a4XTlg25cwL4zxjY8/nqeI6GeuyuMBi0oCVWMKdkQRTxlHCaAsLTn3mMTeO2dB3pqbLfE/AplFA6xlP4oTjmbKQ8xFLY@56Y88VdBifZTxMvShMTea5p@zc83024j42rIi7dSBjebo2JUmZyihSGD5ufIvV5VuZAybkC3F57CRC3IjFQvaF1OeJE8dgUimxQzCeeQFPmZdVUsad1CMdYkvKw5HQVLzUbsSccF1KduY5zAG/eSJwpzzJIJ4p8LIpTzhQOkR8kjgB084TL4MKSJG77IA7CTtKONdBBQbgqevE4OMGSRCLiEJGgpjCUJ1OZe/tmwoMJneYTpwppWTj6N@/Vxxm2qx83MbXVtW2svfza3ZV7tMYXAAZjBonmqMz@5qlVr/P8Z01h9YkmSvAqkArPrOiOLOA2UkysLcaGWctM/bXyLLOLUusOZGEGsEWbD9kH@pCLjdPEg4uVip1TiGyH4UTaBOiJnlI2gjZdgMGcKNwlNYZP4POolBaKDoX@j2aejBZSgZxhlCP45Lm5QEQ6sQRgOcV@lzQTSM/F3DYmWbkftAJthLG/TH7wMaO59MWrBMqyXXC09zPaE8ejsjugRfykckWbLjRiICC6AzkHCAVEzgzwdpJE0wBGGaIhKi09M@//m00mQDPrutGyahw1g9sFLl5AIYdwawDRyR3jULHF2wBrk7U5XYQOHN8b@RkRD68KEgIJgTV8yj3RywCweTcw8GaOmc4jOMxdzMuXTzKM/BYZ4FzKuODJ/0WggfOEIYVBARtIbbBdl7BSi6XDmMEeTZ@yox4j1VS65P24rn24lGfgzfd1Ktly5q04W1mVUzhrfI1x/mwu7Inec@RF9Ep8uNpjpiBlTCNEU0SUqbrQJyUgkqGmFdnQ6FoEYng6OKInvNKwtkQ53ohmPAR6QO036BzW2BY2XQBd9PF@GjNw@CdcLIsvRMk/OgchAVvFDjh0yERdyYOSGWFQLtSIElRzNwU7TSEpxO2IWdPjaEH65AfINQUxliTEeAbLQkDbNJ6a4cicC6AxZUhemVJ5o1h5AB@m1wwl9NhwKngMs4RkVw4RurBj6Ixaxitra3fMX6WWLvGR8sxLq2v2piEv2XmXTbm58x3wknuTODIUYgtjuvyOCtOECRJM5yR22FQTBpFTDfTqVLeuU1bxLYi2q/RoOgjrVdEaIfcHooKoGrDxylnTjIRJ5GNvATnxb@4TR0AZ7eIqycEcoOBE/UBFhYXE5yMz7ibZzhucOTzqedO4bvEXSgPrIyOt8ljap06Qo4xXpImZprdxy3FtJZTxMaDKAyy6F08iPqEqntjQhh/fUIKiJv3kG59hKrFNStOwTIVWMoOZXxPl0jCf82hXPieNwkJxAmXV/RaFPPSsIKw7qUeNESXLfnl0f5bit2/cJlvQEfy3lkPvBGyD2wvLlNaWChM4e40YkbIKgUPmiruvs9gy0oTVwyMtQtf1U1oSyOtiaUFos8yh7p9@bHuXThBslJnPVUd1HHf@CnMHea@j5c8FMdB4/oV/MLlaWrCuXEGTcocwJ1a4/r8JmA2TaJzxud6u3IfuT9pkFf50Jv9P7SIS3zJJ6RaM4OY@iN2uAP4LzbEHXowxX6IWwbx91JcByGFtzzIfSeTGYEb5dDz0hy4Ghy7IS14BB39iCyJ/ejR5TVGTrXKtUV6PqOssq@o8UU2jcKNm@FHXa20ZHr3wQpwG5nxxf0Xr7qOSmz4yQtPI@LNChaj44bZ3LqBAuXB3Z1jL52Kxw3QO2zdXRG702A4Fo97AEJyxVseLxaCKIwkcWjICx3rnfgxEWLv4@BmJLtB/iWHjSfceLZhDb3QGvLxQ5BvXr7cFzDj4dB7CAhqoAJo8XsPWJIP79MSEpjpnZuO3dDzUZ5kvjGyMvrl//sfI@j7rjWmzkWKlPd0OTgO@TlZxhg/aJxiK72Ix/2G/Jz7KId@B4frUJrr@MvB/bies3cc3o6EJBRVEDj1fRxkqAwB5q474yT4@Ygvfu9HKnR488KUu0MvMODL22ZDGBCvlARQKvYQllu3vkRD1UHiR87IkvWax1cWlbrnM2cShRfW2pViJsM/wOriYmarAi2b5lkun1SV/Z7tvJi@XzuCBWRja/dlc6/4eQAeTGw/5Lvy2CSILsYb3zm1hjQ8HmN4v6hSmMSboARc/D4E9sth7LjcOk/p5163@QnplI/C@vDn94cHX/UfgRB5VuLL573o9kMXl1qY/T4mSOmLx59xPOEHruPD@zak71FfxFhTk3dLsb4zvKBCfvrnfYioTmo1ZkSramXVdonjhze57v2bZGNG7HMj1JP8924dXB1eAHFbo7Xhgz7hRcaqJkqlI42pCLwn9jhnDjNc30nhGlmhXX4Ga4jH11yVbgiXfGY1@pqj3mJqUZc@VNqsdsaeG@H2joWZ6cXHy0OX2u3sYYWGGm7isdpKb4W/vubOiK7a6686bORmVFE84DJ3pkUG8k50ZpalUlovGkqY85KigZAue3Sl1SoLnUAUkDReJDdtWaWmU9GaQDU5Qqx9H3oiuXSjRNZasqAX99o//j4qOjYTjpI78FLkUZOQeowoqKbR@QtJt6C@G8cOdXwIB063L9NP49UuS8@9zJ3KRg3ytfdvjp4WVXbR78TLAQXZNS6k3Fgagwcn46IglNyMIi4VXRBe7loIBTvnQcjOvVE2RUp36KFwFlX8orIEJwmBoZyPyFB1ts9GnMKOyJ4/50j4/Cg6FUk7cfKPv8veAhaBDFxjvCAvml1rFBm8vCkKeldmlwsklzyJChCNlAxvzaGRC7gJl/M6c6eOaHokJjMWJT@RkWX/q91DZqDmp1YtdQDa3lgr77777kOvMbCvWWAhBbEofxZ6U781njRTtc4WIO05R8a9vtzA8mq1wtTyTC3Eorag6IItnUo6HNNoLMy1KOED0VEUfsfPRQkv@jQhHUZq1aFKSTO86gK1bO3ZZQ25S4CCxDjM2Bb1szlUgpHsQTLqEIOi2FKesS9sSr5iuKy51cCbVIhPHZDAXmWM60m69ZoPc3G1nbXM1oYtxCkf252uGCV8FFGPrPepfz6w0oVW@v3Zt43WDGqLEoA/tujk7P38@qpsdhtfvqTOBVPVeaUtahn1ucrKVwf7B3uHR7tH7w@hxrleKPCgaP6KRqZTNLbhy3m6OJmF/qgHLvoQoo9NmwXustwqse2T14kzsDjOoLBWy5jSGzXNqdV0fa0lvzdDWITTUmtUtDaVBWdR0bhbWBGHdCorVJStSz9Ml8UmiTCmU@TDEFRNiYwgJUswMrrJdv0UXj8awYzDi4zL4krWl8siUy2xsmMupagzVSHY1L7bwIGVz3ELuidyc1nACczpfT3QPrf@@de/yb5nP8P4P4vxGOP/luNPFmnpbqNM8rhUDanlw/4BSxFapOCBM1uTSVaO8O8wR4EdQINnQiEELpldybvCo/U@QJ8wApRJbkqeKejxZKBNsyx@blkUjCeRPzZFncBnsAMc20RqbP2aUxsah8na3trebCIN5cbZAqHomEwoaZUIdf05U5ly5sX2ydBlnU6HqSjMfW5vt6UirbLzaUM9WTJaBqwi43aPYQ@2rHZgrVts08pOranTVmbbrNKssEEbIVnaBadaEwOA6DQdFvpQETaiQlVU8/NZxuDNycXiPsJlgPoxID2JP0YsEBlAJHHrqnLHd8EvVkRm6t24K811M6i/EJjIY5@r97kOg4f8zz2eE2L8X3Lc6zeM68F9jfSl7@ze7Zdrt7vdJAvbOQwjKlbegFemtazWhtXc1tfOiVqgArd0Kr4AJc4BzpXLvc9RnO6@2tv//u3B4Z1@r4Cs3AarsEq3U@sbZr03WA4q9/j8MvU@ik7B8Vcan0ZGEN7legvUK3ZT37LVtUb8zKLejmJaixXcL1rnBse6bNKuib7gAf5bzJSbKoivCLrKnVJtnZtF7rwkur7zrsyL8Af/KWpFuCT9sY1ac7gjPHCy8wMPQ37BNJyuwIHTOjky7ESvL/7aW1/259ck@bei9Lztc3uVKz/CySpbbXEbtedwr5M@62f9cT8kH2tfWN9YptW@0sq@fWEhLOhdrTy1m7WNaq1WDqtaOaSD8fgxXWLzMs7dsama6gxARtnX24j2OKd2OWyXnY5WHtmtqtiBV9wPV9hwnVrmVdmZW@XHcPM6ZhJO0YRr5VSnjKVhms05@PsceWHZqgdOfKWpTJ3RnzmIfNmr1YgHs3xMDFxb/cMaOMepObTEtdkuwq01CdoiKlVuOutvv5Wa24yp2ry18WhHV9mGZZ31X2s77UrPGbfMX93Bd6ffffexUtLV5qbaDjeVklU9YWrv0cHBgdZq6YcHWvcJe1Ktt7efVuvY16zvsL/gw35VSt2/wIDdje1HOxicdE6UUmdQ6/TMrjHo9pTSlVK6nCslpWR3Zu9q9Om97tbk50d8O8agFx/8uLd7uFdvdYxS6/Xbeuvw/ctSEy9brcUKzdDyBtbf7e2@fvv@qI7hd/sf9t4fvH7reV6cjkbpKJruvN1@u2kNujXTMJhhsu4AXLybfdu9vr6usdp1NcuyqjlTSq@7s/eW0SE@AEDghtHXze7gi1LqlXrWmXWmWQ2/cdZonjZPZxh5s8bnKGlMG9PmqNlszhr8fWM4awwbUXOEJ8e/RoCh1xjPGpNG2AgJKMLAnTVcDMZ4TmhpDCSf8c9rNAh742wGMn5TfD4d64w1Gpvb2tPas@Kf/UinLOOLUukXGdFWo81nXtauSJtrGj9zfE1t9metcUvVcZdqz3R4Z3ND1w2tQXfrpv6p2elo21t6t6ttt3Qsq5WZGiUV7Uq7as51evS0hj7Q5xj1aapSmpfoNIZsc0vHTcH1L5bdtFqb9qxTru3UjB187G6tU/y8KI2E5k1LOT5@vXu0e3xsN0tExrKUktk31WZLPT6uVkicNqWskc9NH/F545mi4lMCnD3kE1CkHWmacuRj/MDhOefneX7Ol59XKJQ@f0ZgimOrCtgRH1NOfMlSBKFoXHErRvOFuvEUyePGE1UpIVBRA61DrcbInHYVahNrjOlit6aflE76lap1RdWedsn09tyqVk5OlE73qsTmxM1cGVFhu/mMuIRrN@edLkblCmGq0JyxEW1GpXK5jGPAuuqG@tZUbPrfFrSDxBMCAlHpS7TVvA6/b5eex5WNzUqfZH36zWgy8VrfsJMvzS/bZcuqVFpbjNklaePmE73UbT0xkRuXBsXcJuYGJeESrSZQVBHFwtGn40/HH1ut1rNnz9TW9m@W9bXLB6vLADzmiE15cF8E3k28nxxKQMNlFMbgpxwBf6lbRsr1vSFp98acVPj6lPhfH5hTiC9hCRqgcnTrIitmVWpE9gY6uxIptzdmGq3iLm7K1F8WOVmehKzRViQQtbPayyGokC8wmwBokgKu5tnNNvM6hAy/iNMFBfosdtRsGvo81AQX3kBvL2GWnHSxe42Xtf21mgSfS7akPG4wkmLLteUr2AuoYne1Yrd@CwDVDmAq/UalEPOPiIGUQltiqLM/Lcat/biS9IVMgoXVYjG/MsVcqWb1oK2Q2NW4rfygufoVXZXt6@DxY/dT3AsGbT2wM/qt1YL2XDnVPAlSzezANprtGMy2s16t5g3sQP9BiwXzgd0AMGgT5lS/Wlo6tAtzpXr9shca1@Gg/qYX1pqDel6vfrQv647dqM/whdrqfv1XKG@hSi2zL2th2@ngS7f2DU3Edlpz2jemaMup5tuXPWdgN/S2j4212hsIAz7Tnl@rDXQQ97F4d2Pbf/zYqfndWds3DJ2gPm28eNPLMBjUbHp/rjmd2YvLXo79zzX82iDj62Ae@27aAPjAXxs6luZbsS55nBF7M7AX2Hb144vqx6r96NFlb2YEg7pU//PGyvDE/IyYX/cRrfpx3bGESkQFr6nfes@/NaspU@vwPii5Hq/tlBxWP2IlXp2G@f8B)

As usual, I replaced literal tabs with `␉` and literal ESC characters with `␛`, due to limitations of Stack Exchange. You can get an easily copiable version of the program from the "input" box of the TIO link above.

### Rundown

This program prints **50** in bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver above. The usual four culprits need testing separately:

- **Incident** was tested using its official interpreter, offline;
- **Deadfish~** was also tested using its official interpreter, offline;
- **Modular SNUSP** was tested online [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html);
- **Reng** was tested online [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).

### Explanation

I was looking at various leads for languages to add. One possibility was to find a language with `#` line comments that could plausibly be added to the "scripting language" line (which handles Perl, Python 2 and 3, and Ruby). It took me a while to think of an appropriate language that could be syntax-compatible with the ones already there, though.

It turns out that the answer had been staring me in the face for ages. If you click the TIO link above, it'll open up the polyglot test driver, which is written in bash. So all this time, I had a tab saying "Bash — TIO Nexus". You'd have thought that'd be a hint, but apparently I missed it. As a bonus, bash is also a scripting language, so the term "scripting language line" is still appropriate.

The bash program starts in the same place as the other scripting languages. However, there's a fairly simple way to split it away from them; in single-quoted strings, `\` is an escape character in most languages, but not in bash. So we can hide bash code from the other languages via `'\'…';`, which is a degenerate statement (with no effect) in Perl, Python, and Ruby, but executed in bash. `echo 50;exit` is a fairly simple way to end the bash program. Well, almost.

The biggest problem here is that bash will, upon running `exit`, continue parsing until the end of the current line (even though it doesn't execute the code in question), so we need to make sure there are no syntax errors on the rest of the line. We have a `'` just after `exit;` that isn't (and cannot be) immediately matched. Later on on the line, `'…'` is used to hide some Brain-Flak code from the scripting languages, but that would unhide it from bash. As a result, we need to change what sort of string literal we're using to hide the code, going from single-quoted to double-quoted strings. `or"'"` does the trick without disturbing Perl, Python, or Ruby (as the left-hand argument is truthy in every case).

We now have an unmatched double quote that extends onto a future line. It was fairly hard to close it without disturbing at least one other language; what we actually do is to change the way we hide code from bash from double quote back to an unmatched single quote in a Python/Ruby comment on the subsequent line, and finally close the single quote at the end of the line after that.

#### Pyth and 05AB1E

Messing around with double quotes also disturbs the languages that were using double-quoted strings to hide code, Pyth and 05AB1E. The main trick we use here is to ensure that every double quote we add has another double quote soon afterwards in order to expose as little code as possible. (This explains the extra double quote on the `__DATA__` line, which isn't necessary for bash.) Pyth uses `\` as an escape character; the main upshot of this is that it limited the scope I had for messing around with strings in the scripting languages, forcing me to use the rather convoluted method above (as I couldn't easily make use of the difference in `\` behaviour between bash and everything else). In 05AB1E, `'` acts as an escape character *outside* strings, and having it escape the leading `"` wouldn't do. So I ended up needing to place a useless padding character (defaulting to my usual `x`; it makes things easier to read!) inside the `"'"` constructs that are used to change between bash quoting styles.

#### Prelude

By far the hardest language to fix here. The problem is that the scripting line, with all its parentheses, was moved sideways, and thus the Prelude control flow (which cares a lot about the way in which parentheses are vertically aligned) was completely destroyed. I thus had to try to reconstruct something that works.

Worse, the current first line (which I really didn't want to rewrite) places something of a hard limit on where the parentheses can appear. It starts off with a nonzero digit (two of them, in fact!), and is soon followed by an opening parenthesis. That's a loop in Prelude, and loops early on in the control flow in Prelude cause a number of different issues (mostly because they cause more code to run, rather than less). As such, I badly needed to open a 0-iteration loop on some other line in order to skip over that code. The `main` line for the C program is highly suitable, but we need to be very careful with where the matching closing bracket is; too far right and the unmatched bracket on the `#R+` line will cause trouble, too far left and it won't comment out enough code. (Bear in mind that an opening parenthesis on one line can match a closing parenthesis o a different line.)

Once that's done, we have just enough space to stick in an opening parenthesis on the Incident line, and we've finally got safely past the first few characters of the program. However, the difference in parenthesis placements ends up meaning that some of the Incident/Whirl code actually runs in Prelude, corrupting the stack. Instead of trying to prevent this, I moved some of Whirl's zeroes further to the right, allowing them to give us a working Prelude program again.

One other small change was on the first line of the program; the final parenthesis of the line was in a position that was very hard to avoid. I added an extra `c` just after the Pyth code to shift it to the right. (Many languages are parsing that point of the program, so it took a surprising amount of trial and error to find a padding character that wouldn't break at least one language!)

#### Incident

Prelude was hard enough by itself, but getting Prelude and Incident working at the same time was nightmarish. Prelude placed a lot of constraints on the code which prevented me freely moving things around, and thus made accidental token construction harder to golf out. For example, Prelude only really needs one `0` moved out to the right, but that caused `00` to become a failed token, breaking some of the tokens we wanted as part of the Incident program (because if two tokens overlap, they're both rejected, and the `00` was overlapping a token we wanted in addition to overlapping itself). I had to move both out to make a fourth copy and prevent it being even considered as a token.

More subtle are the tokens `;'` and `␠␠` (i.e. two space characters). The issue is that these both appear *before* the `kG` that is being used to jump to the start of the program, and thus will break Incident's control flow (in addition to breaking the program's centre point).

Removing a copy of `␠␠` by breaking it up doesn't seem viable. Removing it via overlapping it might be possible (`␠=` is a promising potential overlap), but it's almost certainly less verbose to just add a fourth copy, which is what I did here.

Meanwhile, we can use a different trick for `;'`. Breaking it up isn't something I wanted to try, given that it's used in fairly spacing-sensitive situations. However, it's not *that* near the start of the program (despite appearing on the first line), so it's plausible that we could jump over it (thus causing it to not affect control flow) rather than needing it to not exist. I looked for a suitable token to use for the jump which wouldn't screw up any of the other languages. `/v` appears a little earlier on the first line, and doesn't break anything, and thus that's what I used.

### 50 languages in 1 Kib of code

It was pointed out by @MistahFiggins that my 1025-byte submission would be way neater if it were 1024 bytes (especially as the fiftieth language is a milestone in its own right). This required finding a byte of savings somewhere. In this case, I saved three bytes in the Deadfish~, at the costs of two extra bytes used to make Incident tokens line up correctly, and thus bringing the program down to 1024 bytes exactly.

Previously, the formula that the Deadfish~ code used was (2²+2)²+10×1+2 = 48. The new formula is (3²-2)²-1, also producing 48. Surprisingly, it isn't that much shorter to write in Deadfish~, despite being considerably simpler.

This also gives us a [VIP score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) of .008192. Not only is this a new record, it's also a nicely round number in its own right (which is, obviously, a consequence of having nice round numbers as the inputs to the formula).

Comment: Sorry for not having a TIO >_> (Sincerely, creator of Reng)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Ping Dennis? Also, ais523, you should try to golf a single byte off ;)

Comment: You can cut the space in `puts(z )` if you swap `(` and `P` in line 2, thanks you the prelude leeway you've created. Bravo on this answer. #50in1k

Comment: As it happens, I golfed off a different byte. Now it's at 1024 exactly I don't really want to change it :-) Perhaps a later answer can save some of the savings we have; there are likely a lot more (e.g. there's likely old Incident padding/detokenisation lying around that's no longer needed).

Comment: @ais523 agreed. This answer was always meant to be 1024 bytes.

Comment: Now all we need to add is malbolge.

Comment: I was thinking about bash for ages but didn't think of this. Why doesn't `'\'` output an error in bash (`bash: \: command not found` or similar?)

Comment: Ah, turns out the answer is that it DOES output an error...

Comment: @Muzer: It's a warning, bash can keep running despite the command not existing. Warnings are generally considered irrelevant on PPCG.

Comment: @ais523 It's definitely an error, it's just that bash ignores errors by default. I might try and fix it if I think of another language.

Comment: (It's an error in that a command run by bash exits with an error state... not that it stops the script running. It's similar to PHP/etc. which also ignores errors where possible, IMHO)

Answer (score 56):

## 23. [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 186 bytes

Sorry if this messes up plans...

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::  (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[

print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#46(89999+++++!)=#print(17)#0\32=""<0]#echo 21
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6
```

␛ is used to represent a literal ESC character.

#### Prints:

23 in [Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#Jcu9DoIwFEDhva/AUu@NSQtRuAUr1kKcHRx0VIk/GGQBNcSJ9NVR47ed4Qz4PpEOwYIOL9PnCoQx0hjDuVBK7nDZJEAJMMzjjV7RrO1zXvhd1/kuCJxzY4aZa9Z2C6RgyXDP2ONVN50QFKpzU/IFb1@cYjkR0TeDRBZkrZ7luVYSEy3SxVfwM5IZ/l@aS4wOscoAbHTE2/XeckUMU6@sqlp5J95Tr4fhAw), 22 in Underload, 21 in Nim, 20 in Prelude, 19 in Reng (testable [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), 18 in Cardinal, 17 in Julia, 16 in Pyth, 15 in Haystack, 14 in Turtlèd, 13 in Ruby, 12 in Fission, 11 in Befunge-98, 10 in Befunge-93, 9 in Perl, 8 in Retina, 7 in [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OjogICgyMilTIztuNCIxNCIKIz4zTjZAMTVvfD4gXip0dHQqfisrfn5+JQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKCnByaW50KCgxLzJhbmQgOSBvciAxMyktKDBhbmQrNCleMTw8NjU+PjYyKSM0Nig4OTk5OSsrKysrISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSMwXDMyPSIiPDBdI2VjaG8gMjEKIzgbZGdnaTIbYCB8MXw2&input=), 6 in SMBF, 5 in Python 2, 4 in ><>, 3 in Minkolang, 2 in Vim/V, and 1 in Python 3.

To get to the unlinked languages, click the `change language` button in the upper right of the Hexagony link.

---

Hexagony isn't readable (at ALL) in this format. We need to look at it in hexagonal form.
Note that the 2 ESC characters have been replaced with `␛`s so you can see them - they are ignored, so there are no others in the program:

```
        # v 1 6 / " < " 6
       / b . q @ " ( : : )      A lot more readable, right?? No?
      : : : ( 2 2 ) S # ; n
     4 " 1 4 " # > 3 N 6 @ 1
    5 o | > ^ * t t t * ~ + +
   ~ ~ ~ % # = ~ n J < R " 1 2
  " ; # [ p r i n t ( ( 1 / 2 a
 n d 9 o r 1 3 ) - ( 0 a n d + 4
) ^ 1 < < 6 5 > > 6 2 ) # 4 6 ( 8   | Note that the 0s below can be replaced
 9 9 9 9 + + + + + ! ) = # p r i    | With anything (except "`" or " "), 
  n t ( 1 7 ) # 0 \ 3 2 = " " <     V as far as Hexagony is concerned
   0 ] # e c h o 2 1 # 8 ␛ d g
    g i 2 ␛ | 1 | 6 . . . . .    <-- the ␛ represents an esc
     . . . . . . . . . . . .         character
      . . . . . . . . . . .
       . . . . . . . . . .       A "." is a no-op
        . . . . . . . . .
                ^
                | Mirror wraps to here, going NW
```

For those unfamiliar with [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), There are 6 IPs, which start at the 6 corners. Only 1 is active at a time, and are switched by using `#][`. The memory model isn't that important to this program, but might be necessary to understand in the future. All that you need to know is that 1 int is stored in a "memory edge" (ME for short), and `'"}{` change the ME that is active.

`\/|_><` are mirrors that control program flow.

#### This is how it works:

First line executed:

```
#       A no-op (sets active IP to 0, the currently active one)
 v      letter chars set the ME to their ASCII value - so ME is now 118
  16    Like Labyrinth, 0-9 multiplies ME by 10 and is added - ME now 11816
    /   A mirror that sends IP going NW by wrapping to the bottom
```

The bottom (snippet flipped vertically so you can read up to down):

```
    .   
   .    A series of no-ops. The IP is going NW now,
  .     because of the mirror on the top.
 .
|       Another mirror. This one sends the IP NE, into the h
 h      sets the ME to 104, the ASCII value for h
  #     104 % 6 == 2, so IP 2 is now active instead of 0
```

The right edge:

```
        8  IP #2 is moving SW, starting in the right corner 
       i   Sets the ME to 105
      <    Mirror. Sends the IP going due West
    ""     These change the Active ME - just know that the new edge is 0
   =       Changes the MP (more in specs) - effectively a no-op used to fill space
\32        pushes 23, and mirrors up NE to the !
```

The last bit of relevant code:

```
!          Prints the current value of the ME as an int. Success!
 20(R~     Does things to the ME - irrelevant now
      @    Ends the program!
```

---

#### Things to note:

- Hexagony drops all  s and `` ` ``s before executing, so any changes to those will not affect Hexagony
- I needed to pad the code so that it would be interpreted as a 9 length hexagon, instead of an 8th - be careful golfing below 169 or above 217 relevant characters
- Because of this, the `~~~` and the 2 `0`s at the end can be changed at no harm to the code
- The `=""` just moves the ME away from the previous one so that a new ME can be modified. They can be replaced with other characters that do the same thing at no harm to the hexagony program (`'`s, for example)
- This is technically not comlient with the Befunge 93 specs, because it limits the bounding box of the code to 80 by 25 chracters. However, Most interptreters ignore this spec (like TIO), So I don't personally think it's that big of a deal. If you do, feel free to leave a comment. (If enough really want me to change it, then I will try)
- Hope it's not too hard now.

Comment: This could easily become the most crazy program flow if done right. I was close to getting it done with a size 8 hexagon through some crazy @## method, but 9 was a lot easier once I tried that. Also, [v1 of TIO](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OjogICgyMilTIztuNCIxNCIKIz4zTjZAMTVvfD4gXip0dHQqfisrfn5-JQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKCnByaW50KCgxLzJhbmQgOSBvciAxMyktKDBhbmQrNCleMTw8NjU-PjYyKSM0Nig4OTk5OSsrKysrISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSMwXDMyPSIiPDBdI2VjaG8gMjEKIzgbZGdnaTIbYCB8MXw2&input=) works a lot faster, but you can't switch languages easily.

Comment: I would suggest Labyrinth next, but I want to do that one.

Comment: I'm not skilled enough to write anything like this myself, but in the mean time I'm waiting for Cubix to pop up.

Comment: @pavel I'm not familiar with that language. I assume it's 3D. Sounds cool. There's also some funges that are 3D, might be an interesting addition

Comment: I suspect it's easiest to maintain something like this flow as long as we're still at this side length, and just rewrite the Hexagony code when we go up to the next size. With respect to 3D languages, Trefunge should be fairly easy to fit in, assuming that none of the existing languages panic upon seeing formfeeds. (Also, Cubix was posted earlier but deleted because the poster thought it might be too hard; maintaining Hexagony and Cubix at once could be fairly confusing…)

Comment: @MistahFiggins Cubix is also 2D (the source code is wrapped around the sides of a cube), and it uses the same implicit code layouting as Hexagony (it removes whitespace, pads the source to the smallest possible full cube, and then assigns the cells to their positions).

Comment: In a sense this technically doesn't work in Befunge-93 for a spec-compliant interpreter, since the Befunge-93 spec has a fixed size playing field. Might be worth noting.

Comment: @Sp3000 Ah, I had forgot about that. Most compilers ignore this, as far as I know, because it's pretty annoying. However, if you all think it's a big enough deal, I could try to edit it down to a size 8 triangle where most of the new characters are on the 2nd line. (It would probably take just as long to explain it, lol)

Comment: I think it's fine if you mention your assumptions about the interpreter/compiler and note that it's technically not spec compliant. In a sense, it's just like having a slight variant of the language (cue language-is-defined-by-implementation meta comment).

Answer (score 40):

## 37. [C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (gcc), 776 bytes

```
#  1"16" 2//v\(;@#/;n4"14"
#/*`3 auaaZ<>16/"<"6/b.q@")(22)S#  ␉␉␉␉ 
#yy␉;36!@
# ␉
#=␉>
#[#yy#yy0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#`<`␉|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and( 9 )or(13 ))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
""""#//
=begin␉//
#*/
#include<iostream>␉
int main()  /*/
#()"`#"\'*/{std::cout<<37;}/*'"`"
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>3N.<>␉//
#xx
#x%~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#xx
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  ap
#_~nJ|#o51\   
#0␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>>>#>27.say# =#print(17)#^_^_7LEintndus({})!<>+]/*///Z222999/3!@"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVjLdtvIEV0LvzCbNgCbgEi8SEsemw9L9shzPPHMKJas5IwoUU2gSbYFNjgAKJLR42SbnCyyzybL/Ee2@Yr8yOR2g6QoiRpPIBFoANVdVbceXYVfDHmQ/SSe9eMkJznLchKl/IKlLnkzIzuUZ1vVmjVK@ZCmM0LH@SBJ7QrZeTugImSapqanSTQOueiTfMAIF6NxTno8ZpkW0py0yGi@vCsHxCApo1FBpvWSlMgpZHgeE07C0YiowyBZMpQvcpaOUoZzRgRjEclGLOQ9HioGhE1zJjKeiEyLEk1ODEf32C3vTAYasRSZjWiqRE7ISMm/kHyS0tEI/DSDHECGnA9ZRnheygijGZcAYUrGRKS0HS2hSwgVqwKTC04JhR7jVK2dsTSHpK5alwxYyrAklcz7KR0Sa5LyHNpIMHbJPqMpOUwZs8EFILIspCPIcYclmCWSQy4VcRXYjUZp78d3JYBezHDpKNeMtHb4@@80StwmMTt1/Jq6Xtf2fviGXJptOYYUWAyGGaUWtUnzhmReu83wmwZdr59ea1hVAyox8ZJR7mFlmuYQ73bkXFTdUbzCljTuWWLFEQqqCLYg7wU5qii9wnGaMkhxCyk9h8pxIvpAE6qmYyHREGTbhwHCRERZhbALYJaIwkLJROF7OOAwWSYNQruAh4YS@cK7FZzwbzjRHM8F3yyJx4oOM7Ocx7EEGFPliu975Ij0KI/lFLyXSxVSpywbx7mcMxaRtPuQCxa5ZCFGmESSaJhcgB3FouoB/H64Ei1KKBDDDIlSVb7679//EfX7WGc3DJM0mjvrEYmScDyEwFQJS@GI0l0TQWMlFugqknsxHQwuaMwjmkv2YjZnoYRQXCfJOI5IAobphGeMDOgF4qrXY2HOChdPxjlkrJAhPS9inBd@C8WHtAvDKgaKN9RWTuIMx3nva@KM9kgp806t16@s10/aDPLYrr1pel6/Dg9zN9Uj3JV@zVmOdm9tqEmX2SU9NiExFf0x7UOtRGACDUM2yud4ApcsB2L3g0I9dOYR7mYDzdy5z1l5@jz2V3hIXyyibx6vVIIQJsMhDODEsDmhaV/ZhUQ8BXrx7D53EFzcY66fSZI7Apzpj4iwSFPwajZl4TgH@KxCJgMeDshESScK8xWxcp89Hq1yhwM6vSVrKUzQelbVXG/5SIrx6BKONPTDdZAD5FKtOw@UT6w@UAqqRHwg8zk8d5F1ZWTcJvml8kDjO5lTUvbzGOgiQHlfSBIqlhl7xal5JkqIcp5xQCRzL8ebw/c/ylD@Ayt2EoBUpKHVOEywr2D6PLfKFwvENBYOEuIIUprLYOkqFX6GWF6WhmrgrOR/3XYBlyVhU68WC30utsX7uZC0HtIplqUKOdb1kwrST5zB3mIcx7gZCxUQFrMv4RghyzIX3o1YdeVGAun0MrOv7xLmgzSZEHZt10vr2CmDHELnD0i55ANHtkx6SNC3e7Dar6dyi2pr@miGYkDU7nqvfvumWuwVR96QIhJHs/URra8upSZ8z8V5Ii3vDRejju8GW3eWQL3wcGaPZwN1ukP6QKyHb9TsbNjtqdMaAiFd6x5e6sUwEUnBHAhxQb2P6uIiQtdJcDcQ7rB/w2CqPnNe1rwuF16X9R6jfPfmzXtF0@t2@WNEgEEWRovrGrJ03F2HUpdmgweJktzB@XCc5rETebm8sv/8OQLeD60xoLMM@@f5ctARbCIt4/QeNc58qrxRp/WG/DyOUVt9YY2Qyj2TxsvB@rVekY8M3o49TaiSCpLGMcIRkCFhPHRnREI8jtjiun5RheHdfEsEH8r9YiTr1kdm3NsgCoayrEjjhEZeUehxdmu9Amc2pf1EzLyV5OOm3d8g1iKHk9vKLh@M83FxluXcl@zER/L3a@E2p/S3dt8Ee/PLI/QQYvsxPy1CJEUmcd7F9NzrymGnh@F6VQtlUt5H7bi4PkbGMpVknG6SnDtFvZ552FZR0YxoyFSo3d6u9aHvsTXHKNkPfvh0sP@rzqQ4YrU0Ls5rl3svQuxYIv/ySoAhVqff6IVqknKUkMaO79Z8j4fnxFnBkN9DPabdmWwPBv@/g0mO/XKZOMltVb@chWZPTlK7zkdV2i@rK9T1RUeCZzydV6CZu2jyjNu3RFAUSdim5HhRLtSLIjUbqNoWHUOEmPskuCoQUEsX5VmFdLHlq1z2739F85K/z/KMDHmGkrYvZL@JGmyQTF4rvkVt@3b3gDgobJUMPaI/dV74mV4h5u7Hb4@O/ZMS0c2pPhdU9iyqRF8KXChDLDneV/vBvKIcqnZH6cQmqqJEi4PuRu6Sso9AFZOhQcxttbSFHDhEoeIc5GRL9sssR0G6NW@MiGxbwUmREnNKrtBxout2QhJs@bgrVIllgT5s3m49q7u99w3rjlXcoLWr1ppKD/SOjZYapSxKZBV/fNqOTrxsgQZaxqd@dSrxeOZJU6DNvDTdln91ldGZrl@X7JU@fG@KOgDuLfsh1c9osjeXUCXj/E69PeH5oCgMUS2GAyrLB1kvLoo8KVIPsUti6Cn7FBWsmVSUSDBdshtnaJejCDB1Z7lEdyzyoq5bFne6QYS79KMK0bUHHxTk3AyA54smE51PmioZBtjkCq@CYaIEZBPVYqGKRJ3quq42CaUJ1BLrOiW03Gjbiu6onWP8l/m4h/HfivGpJ03qPWiZCkUe4LeSuPidGJtrvkYKAmb/XCOEwPivxfi47Ts3J@s6tzViLLNZnpwzwf@ksFp8tXhMiFVuutdu61/mteou0HW@LyINyC8SoHoLl@X5K7LzOyYEm5E1n7WK712337ceSrdXuowT5E7Tq6tYqF8DjbM2aeftXltISOoz7yvP9eqXlhk3Z57nhXbLMgfNoFzbLJdNsWmZwgls@9kzGULXZtY0O67u6lMQOWZs1xEMlkmbpqibtGGZUbO6qWbgtly2LzHhBs3zpUmvPfMZcKrgScouEA3MMjNb1ui@6wbXkO9zwoXpVYZ0dGnpRJ/K7yGSvcnLZSmDa3akADde@6AMyQH7gacCtz53NK8/rKvQLt2F/pdfDEICPdjWSdXzLtpWfcfw6uK5HjzXNcPbPKsBVUp/arSCbU9v6Nte1/15R7etatU@wNQNHEQzZrONem37yQ6ss6EZzY2WZhzjIf792B9O/eA8OMeIT/3PU3/gD4IoCIJ9n33yu1O/6ydBhDPDnz/FkPu9qd/3hS@CYOonGIRTP8Sgh3Nfvuphkc/4474v15Yshn4cqMP3rdOOrRlnjbONK00pbVnsgsaWHrSn1V5Vt5FkLPKS2DBQUCO27Vi@zDvP7dOg0bC2t@xWy9qu2nhfstqX@L@25enYsk/sawyKf7tkPN@2vi6/nP81n9hGcNX0moFXfd6cNl8eN8zyTtnZwdFslRvzy2ujVXYdxz3xtE7nm93D3U6nGRiepxlu29WDqr65oek45KNml/W52JAvN/HjIpTFaoMnCDtGh60NTQaMbMwsG0aWNJatnxl6u7TpXaL6f/UK6TFvNGov6tfeZkk/0zWzJOlLalGnljxPDNM0tUar9oPbaKmn0yl@T29ubsob5ZvNPM833al62pSfS7EdgkgKqEQ0/BNDpd0qlLDax@9231aChmNU1eDg0xtD3m3d3lZxW5O3H/a@3fu4t/fHSrD/YW/3YO/b90d7n/aLMbShI83o3IjvroxkK2iDLVh9FfX7vPoVDBtcbZueVypVtwh6YBxGq/rCxdZkkKZRGD14YRunndPOiw97uBXROLNgtCeNVvkESHneT9Vq9eXLl17tyY5e3f4f)

### Rundown

This program prints **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required.

I added another format to the test driver output that escapes double quotes as well as make line feed replacements. This is so I can feed the single line string to a c(gcc) program I wrapped around the function created by @feersum [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107533/write-an-incident-tokeniser/107650#107650). Hopefully others can make use of it as is.

[Here's the Incident token program](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#ZVPrcuI2FP4Nr7B/hM0GybKxZAgpseWQbclOu5lOpmk6ndiGOFy9sQ0NZkchgQforz5jXyQ9wuymnep6js5F39E5etWTfJSuxxPkrYpxsmjO/eq/jx6TfKbOqkleoCxOckyeqwjaaB4/onwiiyBCAmk6QjzUeCfUkGPbX0Ls9nTbzdtwBvPvv/7UbeOuheJ1HN96Pu/YoeaFWse@b/7RCzWCHYdcg48KNKS0n54qbqtT6ykaVdQqKr7aAhDBYCnLJOMP/AGoRLLPks3ZnI8551dscsPuJbtnCz6GdQKdSSATNpVsxnKWcy7ZAoiRZCMgprDOlGgKTj5DTxhTvtUVGUv5vjGGB0OiINx5d5UXIJbwOAXGky9xiiHOUDpTB2KJ8zFGXUQWj5i3ECEWZnCE2mTAPQ93jonv445DQN7A4TOMLVFLgElEtkCUgzT0dgd/R7uHLmpE5y/CFtx22kKKbuDVaY9aPWjCp95hO9N92rSsZmQDwOHwh/Nfz4dDwXVb8XozbAJQAGmoJw21spdCcT@ZJXmlVDT266EOvGQBhTCJM19ZvRUCQnaph0mo3engqmHYz1BGp6ejxbrwvNaJu7WNBgj3JVBvKLvG4QqrtWgv9Hq9Doznt35uev5BIuV@fb/b7WiF7oyiKIym/CYRE3hNhErUhwi@BqGzSJ@M5gvkQMg4DC7Ovze5Z@nOnri@@aAr7viNdYBtKfay/7H/S7//u8mvLvvn1/2PP/7Wv7kqaYg0Xirvw13@04u@OOYhANhf9248myXOOygI/tKp23aj4Rwj5Kum@85JcxU/6UjoZanwE6IPhoPhyWUf2Hy8XmFIdM3zaQQvadu3juN0u127VYM/4XQ0d//Tplh9M@JWt1WjMDO3qr6esXSrn/CIPE@hzNxddnQ0GiyDLHJJJgq1U5q52@oDTkoVoxCZsLi7DJLILQJKk0hk5BNWPHEzwUB5iveeV4cfrhKdC8h8OsnxipibILd2eWReBDnlkbk2jVuxMWPBTAkzPYCFuwqxobkbezApPTj72pZiRWP3P0fK5AGnYhPEkWDETcGQ0gsIAvCtgpTSiMClKQj/b@imR0cxTX3pppZFlNagdXYRFEBEVCj@FMeePNsEa7A/xbALuCYlABrsSOlx@w074HPhbff5mmLtfdNYaRAopeYSYiHVN8BSYZWANRPCuD0zbg1Rq20CaWWRWebglJX6KgqpolApfH39Bw). Ideally I'd like to deliminate the tokens since they are a bit hard to read, indicate the "center" token, and include it in the test driver. But I don't really know how to do anything other than make various programs print sequential integers, so this is as far as I've gotten.

I've attempted to solve the obvious Incident problems, like tokens after the beginning and end jump tokens and anything that looked extraneous, but I haven't balanced the tokens to put `0o` at the center. I'm not really sure what the logic is exactly to determine the center. I'm hoping @ais523 will help there. This string near the end `7LEintndus({})!<>+` would all be tokens if not for this 4th inclusion in the code. These can all be removed (and replaced with a `.` for Hexagony alignment) in order to adjust the center token.

I'm going to be updating this post off and on over the next day or two to walk through the code, (assuming Incident can be verified/fixed without going over the byte count). But it's super late now, and I mostly wanted to get this out there before I had to solve another Labyrinth like problem. :P

### Explanation

### How the C++ code works.

I think most people are familiar enough with C++, so I won’t go into too much detail. Block comments come in the form of `/* comment */`. Line comments come in the form of `//comment`. The actual code utilized by C++ to produce the answer is `int main() {std::cout<<37;}`. And the library that’s used to interface with STDOUT is referenced by this statement `#include<iostream>`.

### /*Comments Abuse*/

For me, the story of C++ goes back to my Brain-Flak answer.

After finally finding #28, I set out to study some other polyglots posted in PPCG and all that studying led me to a few easy answers (most of these are still available to be found if anyone else is so inclined). But more importantly, I came to a conclusion about polyglots in general: large polyglots tend to fall into one of two broad categories: `#` comment abuse or `/*` comment abuse.

This is not a fact or restriction in anyway, but of a personal mental framework that guided my next several answers.

From here I reasoned that if this was to become the world’s largest polyglot, which I presume it to be currently, it would be best if it could leverage comment abuse from both comment families. So I set out to find a way incorporate a `/*` comment language and pushed towards the C family due mostly to a personal familiarity.

### C++ Initial Test

My initial thought process for this was to use C# mostly because of my familiarity and the first hurdle for C# was getting the polyglot into a state where it could accept a line that didn’t start with `#` without otherwise being treated as code by the scripting languages. The Rail answer, along with several byte inflating answers that lead up to it, solved this piece.

Next came the problem of how to initiate the first `/*` comment block. I knew the line would have to start the line with a `#` to remain invisible to Perl, Ruby and Python, but whatever came before the `/*` would be read by C#. I attempted a C# `#region` tag at first, but that turned out to be too ridged for the 2D languages. Enter C++.

C++ has several preprocessor directives that all start with `#`, which give a lot of options for the 2D languages to traverse. But it turned out that all of them were incompatible with at least one language, and being in a C++ exposed code space, I had limited workarounds. Out of frustration and desperation, I stumbled into the fact that C++ would simply accept just a single `#` before the comment block. Okay, whatever, that’s workable. So I moved forward with the presumption that `#/*` could work as the first three characters in the polyglot.

The second piece of basic verification was to ensure that the actual print statement could live happily with the other codes. I knew from the Brain-Flak answer that Japt didn’t like un-escaped `{`’s and that was needed for C++ to say `int main() {std::cout<<37;}` and C++ wouldn’t allow Japt’s escape character in the middle of its code. This time I was lucky enough to find that if I dropped out of Japt’s literal string just for this statement, Japt would still happily produce the same result.

Meanwhile, Brain-Flak didn’t like the `{}` either, but I was again lucky to find that C++ was ok with a `#` between its `int main()` and  `{std::cout<<37;}` statements, allowing the curly braces to be commented out of Brain-Flak’s perspective.

So, with the main problems of C++ proven to be theoretically solvable, I began the arduous process of resolving all the errors I’d introduced.

### 2D Landscape

The hardest part of this answer was by far the reconfiguration of the top two lines of the polyglot. And the most significant problem was the `*`. Underload will not allow a `*` prior to a `(`. It considers this as math operation on an empty stack, which it feels is an error. So the polyglot required a `(` prior to the `/*` but C++ couldn’t allow this. So the solution was to us a C++ line comment `//` on the first line to hide a `(` and then start the second line with a `#/*`.

Next, Befunge really didn’t like the idea of a `/` without something being divided but after studying the existing Begunge answer of `16/"<"6/b.q@` I stumbled on the idea of a number and a string smashed together ahead of the `//`. It worked and I have no idea why C++ is ok with this but it accepts `#  1"16" 2` as it’s opening statement. I’m not going to question it, but I do know that the spaces are required for it to work.

### Line One

Japt turned out to be rather space sensitive and didn’t really want to enter into its backtick based string on the top line, so it and Pip’s backtick got moved to the second line, forcing a lot of linguistic gymnastics on line 1.

- Pip didn’t like most of line 1, so a second space was placed after the first `#`to indicate a comment.
- The `(` for Underload had to be escaped out of Japt with a preceding `\`.
- `#` is a jump terminator in Turtlèd so it was required, but Pyth considers this a error terminating loop, so Pyth needed a divide by null `/`  after the `#`
- I’m not sure what the `@` in the first line is doing anymore, but Pyth and Japt seem to like it’s presence better than not, although `@` is not a meaningful character according to Pyth’s documentation.
- And it looks like the first `;` can be removed at this point without consequence, so I’m not sure what was being solved there anymore, although I suspect it was Pyth related. But it looks like future solutions can save a byte by omitting that one.
- <>< and Turtlèd both basically work the same as before with <>< reflecting on the first `#` and wrapping to the end of line one. And Turtlèd jumps with `#` like I mentioned and ends with the `"14"` string which it prints.

### 2D routing

With these issues resolved, the next phase was routing the 2D languages. Previously the initial `v` was ignored by the Befunges due to the preceding `#`, but sent Haystack and Minkolang down. Now, the initial space attempts to send Minkolang along the 3rd dimension, which its documentation refers to as the time dimension.

Quick aside on Minolang’s 3rd dimension: to me it’s something of a misnomer to call this a time dimension it really seems more spacial than temporal to me. I didn’t really get it until I found [this](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=V%20%20%2E) link that illustrates the concept, and it seems more like the multiple layers of a 3D chess board. My belief is that this is how 3D languages generally operate. But as this was a new concept to me, I thought I’d throw this info out for others.

So Minkolang’s multiple layers are delimited by lines ending in `$$$` which I threw onto the end of the Rail code here: `#-3o4o#$$$`. Now, Minkolang hits the space and falls to first `>` in `<>3N.<> ␉//` and proceeds to the right outputting 3. `#>`couldn’t be allowed to start this line because it would attempt to terminate a Perl6 comment block, so `<` is used instead of `#` to balance for SMBF and Brain-Flak. However, this is a Brain-Flak stack swap procedure, so a second set of `<>` is used after Minkolang Terminates in order to swap back to Brain-Flak’s correct answer.

Labrynth similarly bumps up against the space but it causes Labrynth to moves down in column 1. It then turns down line 2 where it travels down to the `3` hits another wall, causing it to turn south again and hit a `;` which causes the 3 to get popped. Then the program continues to the right where 36 gets stored and printed, before finally finding a `@` exit. This path is longer than it needs to be, but I found that Prelude would output a nul byte before it’s normal 20 output if the `!` was any further to the left than it is now, regardless of the line it appears. So I made it more correct, because I had the space to do so.

Next, Haystack’s routing got changed because `/` now comes prior to `v` on line 1 and reflects its path up like Reng. Fortunately, Reng cohabitates rather peacefully.  The one hitch was that Haystack’s needle `|` was a reflector in Reng, so a Reng uses a Befunge like jump (`#`) over the needle to conclude Reng correctly.

The Befunges continue along line 1 until the `v` and get directed down and then to the right on the second line to conclude with the same code used before. My sense is that this piece can be golfed down a bit now that fewer languages are attempting to meaningfully traverse the code, but I didn’t need any more walls to bang my head against, so I left it as is.

Finally, Cardinal’s starting point is `%` which had no particular need to be lumped in to the already dense top two lines. So I moved it down to Python’s string. Its multiple code paths are also now bounded by `x`’s, which ends the movement of its pointer.

### Line 2 &3

The only significant change here is that all of the `:` got golfed out for one reason or another. Maybe Prelude’s `(` needs or maybe it was simple byte count problems – probably both. The other thing is that trigger’s jump code got moved back and rebranded as `auaaZ`. I had space to fill to meet Befunge’s code path and this seemed best. Also the `<` following this piece is to balance SMBF’s following `>`. Finially, the lone `”` near the end of the second line are to maintain 05AB1E’s string. Also, `yy` on line 3 are just filler characters for Labyrinth.

### The Big String Esolangs

With the top two lines resolved, it was time to start digging into the fuller-parsing esolangs, and Pip turned out to have a problem. If you remember we dealt with the curly braces in `{std::cout<<37;}` by dropping out of the Japt string to let Japt treat this as code. Well, Pip is using the same string syntax and didn’t like this line as code and Pip has very similar string declaration options as Japt. Both use a single `'` to declare a one character string, both use the same escape declaration of `\` and both will accept `"` as string identifiers. So it was difficult to make Pip believe this was a string without making Japt believe the same.

It turned out that Japt did have one exploitable difference though - `#` takes the ascii value of the next character. So, `` #"` `` will terminate the Japt/pip string, then tell Japt to take the asci value of `"`, while telling Pip to start a new string. The `"` probably could have been a backtick instead, and probably would have been better, but my line of thinking was to use a different string identifier on the inside as another point of string manipulation. So here’s another place where you could save a few bytes down the road.

Next, I had to initiate the Japt string after the curly braces while allowing Pip to remain in a string. I did this with `` '"` `` that's a single quote, double quote, and a backtick. For Japt the `'` is not in a string and is therefore an indicator to take the next character as a single char string. Pip sees the `'` as part of the string and terminates its string with the `"`. And finally, `` ` `` is indicates to both Pip and Japt that another string is beginning which continues throughout the polyglot until the last line where both languages complete happily.

Now, both Japt and Pip worked at this point, but 05AB1E failed because of the use of `"` caused some error inducing code exposure. Fortunately this one was easy enough to solve by putting another set of `"` around the whole thing, leaving the set of string manipulations as `` "`#"\\'*/{std::cout<<37;}/*'"`" ``.

Finally, with the line now looking like this,`` int main() #/*"`#"\'*/{std::cout<<37;}/*'"`" `` which Underload had a problem with. The consecutive `*`’s, were another syntax error so I threw a `()` in the middle of the `*`’s to appease it.

### The Fragile Esolangs

The big hurdle now was White Space. I won’t go into a ton of detail here because most of the Whitespace solution is built into the explanations already given, and I just glossed over the instances where whitespace forced a few decisions. I’m looking at you Labyrinth. The big change though, is that the actual code to output Whitespace’s answer is on line 2-4 instead of 1-3. This is largely due to Japt’s code exposure in line 1.

Thutu originally had problems with what had been this line: `` int main() #/*()"`#"\'*/{std::cout<<37;}/*'"`" ``. So, I threw in a linefeed just before the first `#` to hide all the problems behind a comment indicator and then spammed out a bunch of trailing `/`’s everywhere else that was code exposed.

At this point I aligned Hexagony and found new problem. The code at the very beginning, which started life as  `#  1"16" 1` made the `+` in `/+23!@` no longer clear the stack. So, I just removed the `+` is and found it now output 123. This was easy enough to fix by changing the opening gambit to `#  1"16" 2` and golfing the Hexagony piece down to `/3!@`.

Whirl had some changes, but it was mostly a matter of making sure the right number of leading 1s appeared before the Whirl-Incident line. Incident though had one token that was particularly difficult. I had exactly 3 copies of `/*` and `*/`.

I initially wanted to just throw `*//*` any old place in the code to create a 4th copy of each, but Underload saw consecutive `*`’s again, which was a no go. Ultimately I threw a `/` on the end of this line `int main()  /*` to make it end in `/*/`, thinking that I’d make the tokens overlap, but I only succeeded in creating 4 copies of one of the two tokens. Right, right. That’s how that works. Oh well, I’ll just throw a similar `/` in the final `*/` to make a 4th there. After this, I replaced a bunch of hexagony no-ops with a 4th copy of several incident tokens in this string on the final line `7LEintndus({})!<>+`.

### Conclusion

Ok, that's all the detail I have for this massive refactor. I promise not to have so much to write about next time. I actually have no idea if C++ is a good or bad choice for this polyglot, but my sense it opens some options. Hopefully this leads to good things.

Happy coding.

Comment: Looks like `g++` requires a `.cpp`, so I added that to the file extension specific section. Then just had to use `run-wrapper.sh` to handle it. I'll edit it in.

Comment: If I'm following the Incident correctly, looks like another token that has all 3 occurrences after the second `0o` would fix it. Currently, `#xx`, `#0`, and `p` appear twice. Can one of the `a`'s at the end of the 3rd to last line be replaced with a `p`?

Comment: @SnoringFrog Yeah, that looks do-able. I'll update the post.

Comment: I want to add [symbolic brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Symbolic_Brainfuck) to this as it's an easy addition, but unicode characters crash python2 - _ -

Comment: @SnoringFrog I feel the same way about [emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji)

Comment: "Middle token" in Incident is defined as the token which has the same number of tokens before it and after it (or if there's an even number of tokens, one more after than before, as an exact tie is impossible then). C is one of the languages I was considering adding; I'm not sure what the purpose of a null directive (`#` on a line by itself) is meant to be, but they're defined in the standard, so we can expect them to work.

Comment: Also, `**` isn't a syntax error in Underload; it just consumes a lot of stack, which I assume wasn't available at the time (likely because you golfed out the colons). You can top up the stack with parenthesized groups or colons before or between them, or sometimes hide the code from Underload by parenthesizing it.

Comment: @ais523 Aweome. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @ais523 In the very early days of C, to save time in cases where it was unnecessary, the preprocessor wasn't run unless the first line started with a #. But if you didn't want your first line to be a preprocessor statement, you would therefore need a way of having the first line start with a # without having it actually do anything, so you had the null directive. I strongly suspect backwards compatibility with code that used this was the rationale for its inclusion in the standard.

Comment: Anyone who works Java into this earns *every internet point*

Comment: What is PPGC *?*

Comment: @user202729 Programing Puzzles & Code Golf, meaning this stack exchange. I saw the acronym used a few places, but I suppose it's not terribly common. :/

Comment: @Chance PPGC is not "terribly common". PPCG is.

Comment: @user202729 lol. fixed.

Comment: @user202729 Puzzling Programs & Golfed Code ;)

Answer (score 37):

## 3. Minkolang v0.15 (26 bytes)

```
#>>>>>>>>v
print(1)#>3N.i2
```

This program prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in Vim, and **3** in Minkolang v0.15

I hope I don't mess things up by introducing a 2d language

[Try it online!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%23%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3Ev%0Aprint%281%29%23%3E3N%2Ei2)

#### Explanation

```
#                     stops program from moving through time (really does nothing)
 >>>>>>>>             I can't use a space because then the program will move through time
         v            go down
         >            go right
          3N.         Outputs 3 and end program
                      Anything afterward is ignored since program has ended
```

Vim somehow ignores Minkolang, so that's good

And there really wasn't a problem with Python since it ignores the comments `#`

#### Next...

For the next language, I suggest something like ><> since `#` acts as a reflector (so that the direction will change to left and it will wrap to all the way in the right) so you can add code that can be ignored by other languages

Comment: “move through time” wat?

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Minkolang has 3 dimensions (2d = normal, the 3rd one is time). TBH, I don't understand it, it just states that in the explanation on the TIO link

Comment: @mbomb007 What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @mbomb007 4th submission (><>) already posted :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos I posted ><> without even reading you're suggestion. It's such a good choice for this sort of thing

Comment: @BlueEyedBeast 2d languages *are* a good addition to polyglots

Comment: Added Befunge in addition to Minkolang :-)

Comment: @JHM Now we have 2 *more* 2d languages added to Befunge :)

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg I don't think I can do that

Comment: @wat Hm this took me way too long to understand

Answer (score 34):

### 5. Python 2 (35 bytes)

```python
#3N.;n4
print('1'if 1/2else'5')
#i2
```

This program prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang v0.15, **4** in ><> and **5** in Python 2.

[Try It Online beta!](https://tio.run/#gBXAE)

In Python 2, 1/2 is 0, which is a falsy value, which makes Python print 5. In Python 3, 1/2 is 0.5, which is a truthy value, which makes Python print 1.

Comment: I can confirm it works in Minkolang

Comment: `print('1'if 1/2else'5')` breaks on my system without a space between 1/2 and else

Answer (score 29):

### 4. ><> (29 bytes)

```
#>>>>>>>>v;n4
print(1)#>3N.i2
```

This program prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang v0.15 and **4** in ><>

[Try it Online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Iz4-Pj4-Pj4-djtuNApwcmludCgxKSM-M04uaTI&input=)

Code ran

```
#             - change direction to left
            4 - add 4 to stack
           n  - print as a number
          ;   - end the program
```

Yet another 2D language.

Has no effect on Minkolang as it adds characters after the direction changes, gets ignored by Vim for some reason. `#` is a comment in Python so no change their either.

Answer (score 29):

## 28. [Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), 280 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::   (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9) or (13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{}\/^23!@[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21#|/=1/24=x=90/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6$//''25  #>say 27#"26
```

␛ represents a literal ESC character, as usual.

This program prints [**28** in Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**27** in Perl 6](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**26** in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), **19** in Reng (tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**9** in Perl 5](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**7** in Japt](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA),
[**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA), [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#PY3BToNAFEX38wvdTOdpeK9Ep/OAaaFAWLtwoctSAtpamxjQSpoaKb@ObTTm3tyTnM0d4FAaq1WsrH66/cgURhFFUSSlRGZ6hEXtK@MrAal3bzMTNF0qi0nbtpPedfu@vxaQ9PVd/KAMq4WApYAyLjvxvt/VLeLmUL2hMvmRX1hRVa8lhiSbvUTjEd3g9KJ8KtBQHKMNKE0tU7N3MP8@90SXyXXB3jhbIq3o9C/PdCDzLc7d8C/JmBL4fTYzghVsnl8byQY6nRjNfnJMwqkWMB@tt9sdj0rZmc5eae04HEgJ6Wf1JXkGiu0w/AA)

First off, I want to say what a privilege it is to be able to contribute to this challenge. I only heard of code golf a few  weeks ago and I have been absolutely hooked ever since.  The first thing I did when I found this challenge was try to run the code as is in various languages just to see if I could find anything I could work with. This was back when we were on like #6.  I honestly thought this challenge was bonkers impossible, but here we are (#28 Wow!). What I found at the time was that Brain-Flak output the value 2. So I set out to learn it.

Brain-Flak turned out to be pretty great for this kind of challenge because it's fairly easy to learn and it ignores pretty much any characters except `(){}[]<>`. `#` also happens to comment anything after it on the same line, so the only part of the last submission that was ever considered for Brain-Flak was `print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<65>>62)` which then paired down to `((())()<<>>)`. So then the plan became adding superfluous parenthesis to what I've come to think of as the python code.

I modified the python bits to parse in Brain-Flak to `((() () ())()()<<()>>)` which equates to 2 stacks the first being 5 and the second being 3. After that I'm squaring the 5 with `({({})({}[()])}{})` and adding the result to 3 with `({}{})`. This squaring and adding is going on in a string from a Python perspective. I can't claim to understand Python's reasoning here, but I am fairly confident that this string isn't otherwise being evaluated by other languages in a meaningful way, with only a couple exceptions.

Japt, it turns out, interprets  curly braces within a string as containing code, but these were easy enough to escape out with `\` before each `{` in this string. But this bloated up the byte count. Such is life.

Prelude was pretty forgiving with all of my parentheses. An earlier comment pointed out that Prelude would have fits with vertically aligned Parentheses and I happened to only create one. Sweet! The `(` in the top line lined up with the and `(9` in the big line. So I had to add an additional space before the `(` in the top line. My assumption here is that the double space was a comment indicator for something, so adding an additional space seemed trivial, and it worked. I should point out that I tried adding a additional spaces in the `(9)` instead, but Cardinal didn't cooperate.

05AB1E didn't like my first attempt at the Python string being encapsulated in double quotes, but everyone seemed agreeable to using single quotes. Not a big deal there.

Hexagony was the only language left at this point, and I was obviously way past the next hex size threshold, so it was time to get dirty. The `/^23!@` is the Hexagony code and I'm super excited about it, because I think it'll make future additions much easier. This little piece can basically be moved anywhere in the python string without busting any code. This is the full string just so we're all on the same page `'(\{(\{})(\{}\/^23!@[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'`. The `/` here sets the path of Hexagony from SE ->NW to W-> E down this string, which we have a lot of leeway with. (The preceding `\` is to escape `/` for thutu BTW). My idea here is if you make changes, odds are that you'll end up going through this string at some point and you can slide the Hexagony piece around within the string to catch the code path and send it to the proper conclusion. Just take care not to come between Japt's `\` and the `{`. If you have trouble with this, the `@` to the right of the string is just left over from another Hexagony solution, and can be removed without consequence to the other languages. And of course if you happen to catch Hexagony's code path going the opposite direction, you can of course use `@!32^\` instead of `/^23!@`. Also, you may notice that my solution removed the `===2` from the code to keep things under the byte limit. Someone mentioned in here that this was for Hexagony's alignment and I didn't need it anymore.

Finally, [here](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#PY3NTsJAFIVfZZiR9N7WMsxtGaC0TRdduWBhl/wFBZEEW4EG0f48g3vfzhepEI05J@dLvs1pdoldLG5dExz5svdi1a4Ko2NVb3ERA0n7Y5GYcWRHEhJzHB0r2TTipLTkPtfyobOPOHgeep7HGAMiTMQodblyuQidsY5ULytDNjfzPDdry6rrui2COr3z77kiPhIT4Zevh22aA6xPyx1wNT3TE3FcpisGQ2TZgYFyEG3oXpWLc1Do@6B7GIaaMDsYMC0urfA6UzknpxVNAGdY/csLDRG5GgbW8C9BCwPx@6z6KGZi/ficMVKilIGS5AbnYNiVYvD9@bXabLZ0IStVqW@kNAzqMSbC4/KdUV9w0j8) is a little piece of code I found while exploring codegolf that converts a line of text into a Hexagony readable hexagon so you can debug. I'm sure plenty of people know about this, but I hadn't seen it posted here, so it might help someone else too. Fair warning, you have to alter the input to remove the back ticks and carriage returns as well as swap the literal escape for something that takes up normal amount of space to get the code to line things up in a pretty Hexagon.

P.S. While I was writing this out, I realized I had a mistake. I had believed I was clearing Hexagony's memory edge for with the `^`, but apparently I can replace it with a no-op to no consequence. That `^` should probably be a `+` if you try to manipulate this section. I was apparently passing through a `+` prior to this, but future polyglotters may not be so lucky.

Good Luck!

Comment: I was waiting for the rundown and explanation before voting, but the rundown looks good, so I'll vote while waiting for the explanation :-). I assume that all the extra backslashes are to avoid a syntax error in Thutu? Also, interesting approach for where you added your code, which I'm guessing has something to do with Hexagony. It'll be nice to see the full explanation.  (Also, welcome to PPCG!)

Comment: And now I see the explanation; I enjoyed reading it. The "Python code" is actually used by several scripting languages (Python, Perl 5, Ruby), but they all interpret `and` and `or` the same way, so your method of commenting the code out in the scripting languages but not Brain-Flak happens to work in all of them.

Comment: Thanks @ais523. You mentioned the placement of my code. So, I knew I had to place the brain-flak operators somewhere that was visible to the _scripting_ languages and my initial, incorrect assumption was that it would be easiest on a new line. This didn't work for Retina and I didn't want to deal with both it and the 2D language problems I'd create trying to fix Retina, if possible. I was lucky to stumble into the current placement.

Comment: Fantastic answer, and a very thorough explanation! I'm really happy to hear that you enjoy brain-flak. :D

Answer (score 26):

## 2. V (11 bytes)

```
print(1)#i2
```

This program prints **1** in Python 3, and **2** in V.

Just to get the ball rolling and to throw my favorite language into the mix early on. :)

It's a very straightforward answer.

```
print(1)#
```

just so happens to be a NOP in V. (lucky for me) Then `i2` enters insert mode and inserts a '2'. You can try V online [here](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQoMSkjaTI&input=)

Of course, in python

```
print(1)
```

prints '1', and

```
#i2
```

is a comment.

Comment: Is this V or Vim? The interpreter you linked to is technically "V".

Comment: @mbomb007 Well, V is almost entirely backwards compatible, so the intention was vim. I suppose it technically is V though. Is it too late to change?

Comment: Not really, just edit the title in the answers.

Comment: Does V have a way to exit Insert Mode?

Comment: @mbomb007 A literal ESC character will do it (which is why I had to use one in my submission).

Comment: I meant is there a printable character that can do it? Otherwise, is there another way to output in Vim that won't require an ESC afterwards?

Comment: Vim restricts the use of all non-ascii characters... Ah well, no Aheui I guess... :'(

Comment: Note for those testing this out: You need to make sure you don't have a cliipboard carried over from the previous Vim session.

Comment: I don't have Vim installed but I have Vi in which the `i` in `print` triggers insert mode - according to the man pages `r` is replace a character in both languages, why does Vim ignore that first `i` but not Vi? Thanks!

Comment: @JungHwanMin turns out that wasn't the case https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142382/69655

Answer (score 26):

## 30. [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 296 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::T):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12"; ␉
#[␉
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9)or(13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{\/+23!@}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21#|/=1/24=x=90/
#8␛dggi2␛␉` |1|6$//''25  #>say␉␉ 27#T222999"26
```

␛ represents literal escapes.

␉ represents literal tabs.

This program prints [**30** in Whitespace](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**29** in Trigger](https://tio.run/nexus/trigger#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**28** in Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**27** in Perl 6](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**26** in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), **19** in Reng (tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**9** in Perl 5](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**7** in Japt](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/><>#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), [**2** in V/Vim](https://tio.run/nexus/v#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LU/BToNQEDzDL/Ty@lbDbom@vgVeCwXSswcP2ltpA9pamxjQSpoaKb@OqJ3d2UlmDpvp4Jhro2QsjXq6/ZhLjEQULSgSwuohImSmR5iVvtS@tCH17s1cB1WTWutRXdej1nXbtr22IWnLu/hBapYzYdmw7JnHeWO/H/Zljbg9Fm8odXbiF5ZUlBuBIVUH1B7RDY5/DZ/WqCmO0QSUpob72MHsu98z9SdTLnvD@XmJtKLzxfxTB3yDUze8TDKkBP7f6gnBCrbPr5VgDY1KtGI/OSXhWNkwHWx2uz0PrFw0ujFXSjkOB0JA@ll89d15AgtmDsNQsum6Hw).

Whitespace is another esolang with a limited character set. This one only reads tabs, spaces, and line feeds.

So once we take out all the stuff that Whitespace doesn’t read we’re left with the following code:

```
[space][space][space][LF]
[space][LF]
[LF]
[LF]
[LF]
[space][space][space][space][space][LF]
[space][space][space][space]
```

And the code to output 30 is this:

```
[space][space][space][tab][tab][tab][tab][space][LF]
[tab][LF]
[space][tab]
```

So the top 3 lines of the existing code were given extra spaces at the end of lines to meet the requirements. Note that line 1’s tabs and trailing space are in the middle of the line to accommodate ><>’s needs.

Line 2’s space was changed to a tab here. This seems to function Identically to a space for the 2D languages, but visually it doesn’t line up anymore. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

After the instructions to output 30, the game became getting the rest of the necessary spaces and line feeds to do pointless things and compile correctly.

White space happens to have instructions that mark/goto a code location with a label that allows for an arbitrary number of tabs and spaces, so that helped couch the long line’s spaces. It also starts and ends with a line feed, so that helped us up some of the line feeds in lines 3-6.

The final line couldn’t have a linefeed without breaking Retina, so its instructions are to do some arbitrary math and stack manipulation.

Here’s the full code with spaces, tabs, and linefeeds replaced with our notation:

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(:[Space]::T):[Space][Space][Tab][Tab][Tab][Tab][Space]:(22)S#;n4"14"[LF]
#>3N6@15o|>[Tab]^*ttt*~++~~~%[LF]
#=~nJ<R"12";[Space][Tab][LF]
#[[Tab][LF]
#`<`|[LF]
print((eval("1\x2f2")and[Space](9)or(13))-(0and[Space]4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{\/+23!@}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo[Space]21#|/=1/24=x=90/[LF]
#8␛dggi2␛[Tab]`[Space]|1|6$//''25[Space][Space]#>say[Tab][Tab][Space]27#T222999"26[LF]
```

And here is a commented version of just the Whitespace:

```
Push 30 onto the stack
[space][space][space][tab][tab][tab][tab][space][LF]

Output the number at the top of the stack
[tab][LF][space][tab] 

Jump to label null if the top of the stack is negative. (it's not)
[LF][Tab][LF]

Label this location as [Space]
[LF][Space][Space][Space][LF]

Add the top two items on the stack and replace them with the result. 
[Tab][Space][Space][Space]

Store the stack.
[Tab][Tab][Space]
```

Edits:
Hexagony turns out to skip over tabs just like spaces, contrary to my previous assertion. @ais523 was kind enough to update @Kenney's Hexagonizer to account for literal escapes and tabs. I had to modify it to correct my prior assertion about tabs being read as no-ops and to replace literal escapes with `.` because the `␛` character is wider than other characters, making the hex slightly misaligned. [Here the link](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LVBNc9owED3DX@CiWFssoeBFwjgYWx7OOfTQ5IYJdsAQOtROMWFgjP3XqaDRx672ad@8J12/yox8HdbjoNoVy3QHGMBCh1FQlzhLYtKK8zniJjhjBx0MKgY7fUbEJY8YfGgphj0hIO8xyPuS8253n62KGkoNC8d27JNp6sOOB@tizyDVkAeQhgxWWvXuDFMKwStDaEp0KkhrhG6c46NB9tkx25cZg5IbOhk4jqyNud/FNgd8/JN@Vswm9omk7@VNHrZC3Dw4sLgZaDB@EcZ5aTIS6Jrj536bH65Xekykh1Zoefju/J1abEImk1c@IaRlBpkwpfgLDXLXkq7VptHwpzeVo@IStd56h8Oh1wjRNM2PNtVN/hz@sqSyAtJq05nZSZhc2ncdxrJjumOWjE9qrSye5ivCfG7@QQ4577PBDXD5G5M8DJk34lHkKXNts7gyq@YmxCjU8GFazxif8/obvGebuh4bC/976geu6X9Z@cTpnGbLj4IoSS@oJSpXn7Q/wDYdd1abzVZ1Wgm5yIsHiLatRoTQqEzP5u3qib4qpXzft5T3Dw).

And this is our corrected current Hex:

```
          # v 1 6 / " < " 6 /
         b . q @ " ( : : : T )
        : : ( 2 2 ) S # ; n 4 "
       1 4 " # > 3 N 6 @ 1 5 o |
      > ^ * t t t * ~ + + ~ ~ ~ %
     # = ~ n J < R " 1 2 " ; # [ #
    < | p r i n t ( ( e v a l ( " 1
   \ x 2 f 2 " ) a n d ( 9 ) o r ( 1
  3 ) ) - ( 0 a n d 4 ) ^ ( 1 ) < < (
 6 5 ) > > 6 2 ) o r ' ( \ { ( \ { } )
  ( \ { \ / + 2 3 ! @ } [ ( ) ] ) } \
   { } ) ( \ { } \ { } ) ' # 4 6 ( 8
    + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + = ! ) = # p r
     i n t ( 1 7 ) # ] # e c h o 2
      1 # | / = 1 / 2 4 = x = 9 0
       / # 8 . d g g i 2 . | 1 |
        6 $ / / ' ' 2 5 # > s a
         y 2 7 # T 2 2 2 9 9 9
          " 2 6 . . . . . . .
```

Finally, I golfed out some needless characters, mostly added previously to line up Prelude parenthesis and Hexagony hexagons.

Nim’s code is back to `echo 21` from `echo 5+5+11`

Hexagony’s `#@46` is now `#46`

Hexagony’s code is back to `/+23!@=` from `/+23!@`

Prelude’s parenthetical alignment of `(9) or (13)` became `(9)and(13)`

Well, that’s all I got. Good Luck everyone!

Comment: Verified working in Trigger. However, the start of the last line is confusing me; are those literal ESCs there, or spaces? You might want to use a Unicode ␛ to help disambiguate. (The TIO links also seem to be broken, meaning that they can't be used to disambiguate either.) Also note that SE replaces tabs with spaces, meaning that it's hard to get at the source code of your program unambiguously; it'd help to have a hexdump or some similarly unambiguous form.

Comment: failed to verify the whitespace

Comment: ^the tio link for some reason lacks the code.

Comment: Here, [I modified the Hexagonizer](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#HY5BTsMwEEXXPQMbL74SO249BDZIrnsJlgQFN3EhKDhV3KJWUbpn1z2360WCw2r@jObpv@kYHDsedk96aLvKtiCN0qw3egz08lawwr8Svesz3S3odv29XX9IDxytORNRJTYcHyaXj5mU8BmHX@VCJEnv6m5EMChVqtJTfFqhFXrX9RzWwGvYNUdtHrJ/Iq5SiiECl0BqgB0JSeFpGS@9@3Z9cBxBRJzdK5WP0fCzazxo@WX3A09ZemJ2G@Z6NFLODgrlLHCh4llG/xAnMSQx7vvGH6bJbqtF7f4A) to handle literal tabs and ESC characters. (Credits: this was originally written by @Kenney and modified by me.)

Comment: I think I fixed all the links and added ␛ in places of the space that resulted from my copy pastes. Not sure how to get tabs to be tabs in SE, the code in Tio should disambiguate. I also had to re-create my solution from the instructions in this answer, but somehow ended up with 2 fewer bits... Oops?

Comment: You can do Trigger in TIO now.

Comment: Just noticed a mistake in your explanation: carriage return (ASCII 13) is a different character from line feed (ASCII 10). The vast majority of languages (including Whitespace) care about the 10s, not the 13s (and it's assumed that a line break in a PPCG submission is just a single ASCII 10 unless otherwise stated, because the 13s tend to inflate your byte count to no benefit).

Comment: @ais523 thanks for the explanation. I've always assumed line feeds and carriage returns were synonyms. TIL. Updated explanation and added trigger link.

Comment: Your hexagony explanation image is wrong ([prints `e23`](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#fZJPT8JAEMXv/RSPNoYujYX@EaVSwtkDB/VGIUHFaGJAPRgTwa9ef922mBhiJ9O@nfdmdna2pdrH04ciDdWXqzEOclruTqHeNCXqK7N2K9OyGWRtGXSMGd3Ia@hLbZSSGNm3p4kSzSg@rflIZ9pqRzjUUr2mUE/fCqwgAFV2QmrOd6Mruru2BeNK4bJDCDlvUj3onV71rmfEIRIfW3O4lV5AVWKhT7p8xF16XTkIH6BGLLYk@kgSsNEpeEAivJOyXlrOsMUYNKR3Q@cTUFznOupCFPpq3nvCNSoYbIAsUYeepjBzGKMFvv@jZV0drQ51OVLKDr4uKDD6dTufCufqoMvRHY5t@zyvR2wgFvha93qiyRjKY0Z95c0dReCYTXLmklNywNpOs73i8Lgd/o//2WNkWf4A)) because of `;` after the e when coming up NW after first reflection. The above link works tho...?

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that the TIO for Hexagony treats tab characters as spaces/newlines. The image you provide of the hexagony program does nothing but exit if you follow it (or put it into TIO, replacing tabs with `.`s). However, copy the code in the image into TIO, except remove the training `.`s (not part of the actual code) and all  the ␉s. It prints 23.

Comment: The image ends up hitting a `#` with 118169 as its ME, activating IP 3, which hits another `#` with ME 9, (so it continues unaffected) up NE to the `@`. [This](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@6@goOAZoGCgoGunoKxQpmCoYKagr8DFxaWAEzjgltPGKWWES0ZDAYdMCg4JTSxiXNhNxgTVCgo2ugrGCqkVmSXFXERqikFoyytJLcKmzwyLEzIxxfQxhNLRRZTRBCyBEEVED4y50ETQxPTgNJexQmJ6Ymaegq4@kIcNgrwGTALGWAMxBixnwPX/PwA) is the path it takes. Also, from [the specs:](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony) "Hexagony first strips all whitespace characters." - pretty sure this means tabs too

Comment: Wow, thanks @MistahFiggins!  It looks like I made some deductive errors and propagated them to my explanation. I've corrected the Hexagony explanation, hex diagram, and Hexagonoizer Perl script, as well as cross checked the result against Hexagony directly. Everything should be good now. Good Find!

Comment: Which language needs the bunch of `/\{})([]`s in line 6?

Comment: @MistahFiggins The string `({({})({}[()])}{})({}{})` are a couple of math operations in Brain-Flak. All the `\ ` s are because Japt doesn't like the `{}` in what I believe it perceives as a string, so the `\ ` s escape out the `{`. I wrote a bit about this string in answer 28, and how it can interact with Hexagony if that helps you. :)

Answer (score 26):

## 38. C, 804 bytes

```
#  1"16" 3//v\(@#/;n4"14"
#/*`3 auaaZ<>16/"<"6/b.q@")(22)S#  ␉␉␉␉ 
#yy␉;36!@
# ␉
#=␉>
#[#yy#yy0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#`<`␉|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and( 9 )or(13 ))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
""""#//
=begin␉//
#
#*/␉
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include␉<stdio.h>
int main()  /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);;}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>3N.<>␉//
#xx
#x%~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#xx
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  ap
#_~nJ|#o51\   
#0␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>#>27.say# =#print(17)#^_^_7LEintndus({})!<>+]/*///Z222999/(3!@)"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVjJdtvIFV0Lv9CbMoA2AZGYSEtum4Mlu@U@7ri7FUtWclrUUASKJCywgMYgktZwsk1OFtlnk2X@I9t8RX6kc6vASRLVTigRLBSq6r1334xfNfEh@3E0HURxTnKW5SRIw0uW2uT1lOzQMNuqN4wkDUc0nRJa5MM4NWtk582Qcp8pityexkHhh3xA8iEjIU@KnPTDiGWKT3PSIcnseFsMiEZSRoNymdKPUyK2kNFFRELiJwnpRXRo@1iWxSPxKGdpkjJcM8IZC0iWMD/sh74kQdgkZzwLY57ZJPQvyDiMIhKwCBuWdP0aDiNFtjJVUrGVIFYIPn5yj8vFnc6whi8kZQlNpaQxSaTYc4HHKU0SMKlo5ACM5@GIZSTMKxlhNAsFrtiSMR5IkJIF4jGhfFVKchlSQsFvkcqzM5bmEM@W55IhSxmOpIL4IKUjYozTMAcEAsNdss9oSg5TxkxQAfYs82kCPu6QBLFYUMiFILbUUatV2fvpbQW6KnfYNMkVLW0c/v57hRK7TfSzJr5tVW0qez9@S670rhiDCxwGfSapQU3SviWZ0@0yfCdezxmkNwpOVYBKRJw4yR2cTNMc7C1H1mXdTqIVsqR1TxMr9lOuCqAL8o6To5qUyy/SlIGLJaT0AiJHMR8ATYiaFlygwcm2CwX4MQ@yGmGXwCzmpYbiscT3cBhCZZlQCO0BHuoL5EunkHDCLWB5MzzndLM4KuQ67MxyYX7ABFvFie/65Ij0aRiJLXgujiq5TllWRLnYU/BA6H0UchbYZM6GHwdi0Si@BDmKQ@UE3GW04mSSKSyGGmIpqnj0n7/9PRgMcM6u78dpMDPWIxLEfjECw1QyS2GIwlxjTiPJFtbVBPVyOwhc0igMaC7I8@mMhGRCUh3HRRSQGATTcQjHGtJLOGO/z/yclSYeFzl4rJERvShDQ1jaLQQf0R4UKwlI2hBbGok1KvL@N8RK9kglc06NVy@NV0@6DPyYtrmpO86gCQuzN@UU7iq/ZSxHu0sdKsJkdkmfjUlE@aCgA4gVc2ygvs@SfIYncMlyIHbfKeSkNfNwOxsq@s59ytLSZ76/QkPYYul9M3@lAgQ/Ho2gACuCzglNB1IvJAhToBdN71PHgst7xNVzseQOA@fqIyzMwxSsmk2YX@QAn9XIeBj6QzKW3PFSfaWv3CePqVXqMECrvyAtmPE6T@uK7SymBBuPHmEJRT88BzFAHNW5MyFtYnVCCigD8YFIArDcedQVnrHMDAvhgcb3Iqak7JcC6MJBwwEXSyhfROwVow4zXoGXh1kIiETsDfHk8N1PwpX/wMr0A5DKMLTqhzGSEbbPYqt4MEdMYf4wJhYnlRkPhipD4Sew5WSpLwfWSvxXTRtwGQI2@Wh@0Kcym96PhaTzcJ0kWamRY1U9qSH8RBn0zYsowk3BpUMYzLyCYfgsy2xYN3zVFokE3KlVZt7cXZgP03hM2I3ZrKwjJxVyCJnfI@SS9yGiZdxHgF4mbpnmJyJFdRU1maKG4I271qsun9TLXHHkjCg8MZmu92h19Si54YeQX8RC885oPjpzbW/rzhEoMx7u7IfZUF7uLH3A1sMncnc26vXlZc0CLkzrHl7ywSjmcUkcCIWcOh/kjw0PXcfBXUe4Q/41g6oGzHrRcHohd3qs/9jKt69fv5Nr@r1e@NgiwCCqqfnvmmVp0VuHUo9mwweBktzB@bBI88gKnFz8sn//KQDeD7UxpNMM@fNiMTjjbCw0Y/UfVc5sq7iRl/WK/FREqK2@cIZPRc6k0WKw/qyX5AODtSOncVlSgdMogjsCMgSMh@YMT4iKgM1/1x8qMbwbbwkPRyJfJKLYfWTHvQRREhRlRRrFNHDKQi9kS@2VOLMJHcR86qwEHzvt/Q9szWM4WVZ2@bDIi/Iqyrkv6SlMxPe33G220t3afe3tzX4eWQ8mth@z09JFUkQS621EL5yeGJ71MVwvailMGg5QO85/H1vGMhlkrF4cX1hlvZ45SKuoaBLqM@lqy9u1NvQDUnOEkv3gx48H@79pTJIiTkuj8rr2uHfcR8bi@ZdPAgyRvPyPVig3SUPxaWS5dsN1RLdlrWAY3kM9or2paA@G/7@BCYqDapVY8bKqXzZzSfL4Jt9fv6ls98Q@ma0@yJZgUZWhHyg7GcyF6axyzRbNobZ8SjhFcYX0JsbzMqNZFrfZUNbE6DQC@OpHHsrCAjV4WdbVSA@lgoyB//pnMGsVBizPyCjMUAoPuGhuUbsN4/ErSbesid/sHhALBbHkoU/Ur63nbqbWiL774bujY/ekQlR9os4YFb2OLO0XDJfCEEOM92UemVWiI9kmSZnYWFaiaI3QFYnsKvoPVD8ZGsvclEcbiJ0jFDjWQU62RHPOchSyW7OGioh2F5TkUqJPyDU6VTT5lk@8LRd3pSiRKOxH7WXKWq0SnG9Zr5D@hpaw3mhLOdBztjpylLIgFtX/8Wk3OHGyORpoNb926xOBx1NHqALt6ZVud9zr64xOVfWmYq7073sT1A9wC9FHyT5IET29gCou8jt1@jjMh2VBiSrTH1JRdog6c14cCpb68HkSQU7R30gnz4SgRIBpk90oQ5sdBICpN80FugXPy3pwURSqGuH2wo5qRFUevIgQezMAns@bU3RMaSp5GCI5llYFxQQxlo1la4bqE/WtbdvK2BcqkEes67DQqqPdK7uqbo7xn2fjPsZ/LcenjlCp86DVKgV5gN9KwAvv@NhM8jVcEBD7xxomOMZ/KcfHXde6PVnX8a1hYxEF8/iC8fCzxGr@tuMxJlapqU63q36Z1qq5QNZZPkUYEG8ysOoNTDbMX5Kd3zHO2ZSseYtWvl5bvk57yN1e5SqKEXN1pyl9oXkDNM67pJt3@10uIGlOna8c22leGXrUnjqO45sdQx@2vWpjs1rV@aahc8szzadPhQvd6FlbP7NVW51gkaVHZhPOYOi0rfOmTluGHrTrm3IHbqtV8wobbtF0X@n0xtGfAqcaZlJ2CW9ghp6ZorZ3bdu7AX@f4pDrTm1EkytDJepEvEcR5PWwWhU82PqZYODW6R5UwTlgP3Ck4zZnhuYMRk3p2pW70P/6q0aIp3rbKmk4zmXX2NGcJn@mes9URXM2zxsAldKfWx1v21Fb6rbTs3/ZUU2jXjcPsHMDH6Jo0@lGs7H9ZAfK2VC09kZH0Y4xiX83ckcT17vwLjAKJ@6niTt0h17ged6@yz66vYnbc2MvwJXhz51gGLr9iTtwucs9b@LGGPgT18egj@tAPOrjkE/4C11XnC1IjNzIkx/XNU7PTEU7b51vXCtSZsNglzQyVK87qffrqokYY5AXxIR@vAYxTctwRdh5Zp56rZaxvWV2OsZ23cTzitG9wv@NKS7Hhnli3mBQ/psV7dm28U31xeyv/cTUvOu20/ac@rP2pP3iuKVXd6rWDj7tTrU1@3mldaq2ZdknjnJ29u3u4e7ZWdvTHEfR7K6tenV1c0NR8RFT7R4bhHxDPFS0TQfYBqyPILjxmaDj/syQLyt@xfJeqY1v1Jdq4zmUFnJfFMIbLdEzxPawowifEj2fYcIONnGWYZ5r593KpnMl0rHx2Ww2b5zNyvm5olfEwoqkaDXiZ7Gm67rS6jR@tFsdOTuZ4Pv17e1tdaN6u5nn@aY9kbNt8QoWqRKLBPeSf8090WRIrkNCo3v8dvdNzWtZWl0ODj6@1sTd1vK2jtuGuH2/993eh729P9a8/fd7uwd737072vu4X44hBk0U7eyWf3@txVteF2RB6qtgMAjrX0Hr3vW27jiVSn2LoK/uaJ36cxtJSyNtrbQH77mpnZ6dnj1/v4dbHhSZAX0@aXWqJwDIcX6u1@svXrxwjMaTHVOtb/8X)

### Rundown

This program prints **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required.

Here is my slightly tweaked version of the Incident [tokeniser](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#ZVTdcuI2FL6GV9gbYZMgWTaWTEKW2HLItmSn3Uwn0zSdDrYDDhjwxjY0mB2HBB6gV33GvkOv0yNMknaq3/Ono@8cH/lFjbNRshpHyFnm43jenLnVf4se4mwqZdU4y1EaxhkmT1UEbTQLH1AWFbkXIIEUFSHuK7ztK6hlmt983FVNOzsCEcy//vxDNbVhC4WrMOw7Lm@bvuL4Stu8a/7e9RWCLYtcg4sKNCStHx8rdqtd60oaVeQqKq7cPFDBYAlLC8bv@T1QccG@FmzGZnzMOb9i0Q27K9gdm/MxrBF0VgAZs0nBpixjGecFmwMxKtgIiAmsU6magJOv0GPGpG95RcoSvmuM4dsBkRCGzrDyDMQCcpNjHH0LEwxx@oU1sSCWMBtj1EFk/oB5CxFiYAYidERuuePg9jFxXdy2COgb2H@CsSFy8TAJyAaIcpCGetTGH2ln30WNqPxZmIKb1pEoRMdz6rRLjS404VJnv52pLm0aRjMwAeBg8P35L@eDgeCqKXm16TcBKIDUZEp9peylUtxF0zirlIZyauYu7@NoEmdRZY3QMl5H8wlqjBoGP/OV1kdfOYXtpPy@@5qpvJURCN9rBiFT23nGZKgO/YZmPi1W@RKviW1vTK0xHIKy3pDGjT0GozU/mqv1eh0Yx2391HTcvaYoduvBdrulFbrV8jzXmsWbRkSQboTKsPYhvkapskCNRrM5siAn2Pcuzr/TuWOo1o64vvmkSu74nbWAbUn2sve593Ov95vOry5759e9zz/82ru5KmkIL1xI74Nt9uOzOj/mPgDYXfdhPJ3G1geoGP7crptmo2EdI@S6rupaJ81l@KgioZaVxE@Ieju4HZxc9oDNxqslhjqoOS4NIHmm2bcsq9PpmLhV6xJfsdqKvXuJEyyfIbGrm6qW66ldlU9TW9jVL3hEniZQh/Y2PTwc3S68NLBJKnK5U5ram@o9jksTLRepMLi98OLAzj1K40Ck5AuWPLFTwcB4gneel/s/gPy6mYBfRBJleEn0tZcZ2yzQL7yM8kBf6VpfrPVQML2AGQuuJ3vAcF8u1jSzQwcmpXuHr20hljS0/yOSR@5xItZeGAhG7AQOUnoBgQDGpZdQGhC4OAHl/w/ayeFhSBO3sBPDINLqtnV24eVABFRI/hSHTnG29lZw/hTDLuCahABwOEdKj5s37IDPhvySneCp@o6vkNAKgJYKofXPtL4marW1VxhpoJdpP2XlKQm6kKBL3/EEa32CdnUwwcpBfHrQ1JZ@pugxpZBHfbE31PrALyh9hbR5efk7mxujcDSL/gE), designed to be a bit less golfed but a bit more useful.

### Explanation

I've always loved making little polyglots but never one as big as this; I thought I should probably give it a go!

After @Chance's wonderful C++ answer, C seemed the next logical choice, and given (compared to some previous answers) the relative ease of adding it, I decided to go for it when I had the chance!

I used a very well-known trick to tell the difference between C and C++; the sizeof a character constant is 1 byte in C++ but the sizeof an int (guaranteed to be at least 16 bits) in C. This code should be very portable (except maybe for systems that use bytes with enough bits to fit an int) unless I've made a stupid mistake.

I firstly tried to do a `printf` with everything inline, but the multiple brackets seemed to be causing issues for Japt, so I made the line simpler, which appeared to fix it.

Next, Cardinal didn't like it, I guessed because of the `%` in the printf, so I had to solve that one by switching to manipulating strings.

My next attempt, trying to assign a string then change the second byte contingent on the C behaviour, ended up far too long and would have pushed Hexagony onto the next size; I wanted to avoid redoing that by keeping it within the extra characters I had to play with! I needed every byte I could get for this, so I implemented the byte-saving changes suggested by @Chance.

So I golfed that C code down a bit and came up with `puts(sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37");` which almost worked, except that Underload was segfaulting, presumably because of the complex expression in the brackets.

Even after removing the extra `>>` that used to be required to match the `<<` in Perl6, I couldn't get a concise enough way to split out the more complex part of it into a char array assignment. So I ended up looking at using the preprocessor instead.

After a lot of trial and error I found a solution that Retina seemed to like. Prelude which was causing me problems on-and-off all the way through, ended up fixing itself before I got round to looking at why it was breaking (I guess either the brackets or the `!` I had in the ternary at one stage, looking at previous answers).

All the while I was patching up the whitespace to get something that Whitespace would like; I found that to be rather easy. Specifically, `tab space space space` was a very useful combination (the instruction to add the top two items on the stack), since it meant I could add whitespace to lines with no other whitespace without having everything go out of sync (I'm guessing its position in the program means it never actually gets executed so I'm not worried about stack underflows here).

I've now tested Incident, and it works! Many thanks to @Chance and @LliwTelracs, which I've just realised is NOT a Welsh name, for helping me get to grips with it. See this [syntax highlighting](https://tim32.org/%7Emuzer/incident.html). I have removed the `;` token that was appearing before the `#yy` token. I did this by simply adding an extra `;` after the `gets` statement (my previous attempt involved replacing `s` (which now appears much more in the C program than it did in the previous one) in the "detokenising" string with a `;`, but it turned out I was actually a character short for Hexagony (thanks @Chance), so after attempts to add an extra character to this last line failed, I just changed it back and added the extra semicolon elsewhere).

I have also tweaked the whitespace a little to change some other tokens to make some attempt at centring, to re-tokenise Tab Linefeed (by moving the tab at the end of the `#include` line to in the middle, thus making three tokens), and to de-tokenise the triple-space token by moving one space in the `define` line.

Finally, a day after initial submission, I decided to get to the bottom of the scary preprocessor warning that gcc produced (and which made Clang fail). I determined that the reason the first line worked at all is because it's the output from the preprocessor that provides debug info like original filenames and line numberings. They didn't like the first "2" on the first line, because this meant "returning from an included file into the given file", and obviously that's impossible given there haven't been any included files. After changing it to a "1" (start normal header) made a few too many languages choke, I changed it to a "3" (start internal component header), which broke only Hexagony, since it was now relying on the 2. So at the start of the Hexagony code I added an open bracket `(` to decrement the 3 to a 2, then a close bracket `)` after the end (`@`) of the hexagony code to satisfy Retina, Prelude and Underload which all expected matching brackets. Re-testing Reng and Modular SNUSP produced no issues, and the Incident tokens looked right, so I had now fixed it! I've tested it on a variety of exotic architectures and it appears to work. I know it's not important for a code golf, and I won't mind if future submitters have to break this again to keep within a byte count or whatever (or if anyone's already started based on this solution and doesn't want to change theirs too much), but there is one good reason I've done this - TIO's Objective-C compiler only supports Clang, so this'll be very useful if anyone wants to add that!

Bear in mind I've never used most of these languages, I hope my success encourages more newcomers to give this a try!

Comment: @LliwTelracs Huh, the C program linked by Chance in his answer had a different output for the list of tokens: ;#yy;#yy#yy0l0m1k1k0l0i0j0h0h1d0e0b0b0o1d0b0e0e1d0i0f0g0n0n0o0n0c0c0o0f0c0g0g0f0h0j0j0i1k0m0m0l^_()z   z()()z;      ^_^_

Comment: The error was that I was copy pasting the value to my program so it couldn't recognize the tabs or escapes

Comment: @LliwTelracs Just trying to figure out the tokenisation myself, it looks like I've now got a semicolon appearing three times. I could add an extra one except that I don't think I can spare the byte as that'll misalign Hexagony. Hmm...

Comment: @LliwTelracs I've now figured out how to get rid of that semicolon token without using an extra byte (I somehow missed the bit about the detokenising string at the bottom which I could modify; very useful!). I don't know if the centre token is right, but I hope so!

Comment: the Stack overflow treatment of spaces made me take a while looking for why my code was getting 3 spaces in a row as a token but the C program was not.

Comment: @muzer Ignoring the incident jump tokens and the actual incident code, my solution was balanced with one token on the left `␉␊` and 8 on the right `p()␉␊␉␊()()pp `. The token's here being `␉␊`, `p`, and `()`. Yours has none on the left and 9 on the right: `()z␠␠␠z()()z␠␠␠␠␠␠` with the tokens being `()`, `z`, and `␠␠␠`.  I believe as long as the number of right tokens minus left tokens = 7 then everything is balanced. I'd try eliminating the triple space as a token then create a token weighted once on the left and twice on the right. Maybe there's one available in the detokenizing string?

Comment: @Chance Thanks for that! I just made a less golfed more useful version of the C program, and with its help I think I've managed to sort out Incident in this. I will try to test it when I get home (archive.org is blocked on the train and esolangs wiki appears to be down).

Comment: I noticed one more thing. Hexagony is outputting a couple trailing nul bytes because it's alignment is one space left of where it wants to be. Throwing in another character anywhere before `/3!@` will fix it.

Comment: @Chance Oops! Cheers, dunno how I missed that. Trying to add an extra character to the detokenising string in last line seems to make Prelude go insane, so I'm replacing the semicolon back with an s, and adding an extra semicolon after the "gets" statement.

Comment: Incident works!

Comment: @Chance I've just been looking at how that first line is valid in the C Preprocessor, it looks like it's the output from the Preprocessor used for debug info etc. It means "now returning (2) to file with name "16" line 1". I think it's the 2 that makes Clang choke (and gcc warn) since it never went into any files in the first place, so there's nothing to return from. When I get the chance I might experiment with changing it to something else to make it compile in Clang too. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output

Comment: @Muzer Cool! Thanks. I love how much out of the norm stuff I'm learning from this project.

Comment: @Chance Just fixed compilation in Clang. I discovered a potential future use for this is Objective-C, since TIO only supports Clang for that language.

Answer (score 25):

## 20. Prelude, 167 bytes

```
#v`16 "<" 6/b0\ .q@#;n4"14""
#>3N9@15o|R"12"*^*ttt*~++%
#=|
print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62);#35(99999+++++!) =#;print(17)
#       ~nJ<
#
#gg99ddi2` |1|1+6
```

Literal ESC characters in the same place as in the previous submissions (between the `#` and `g`, and between the `2` and `` ` ``, on the last line), because you can't take Vim out of insert mode with printable characters.

This program prints [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), **19** in Reng (testable [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYgIjwiIDYvYjBcIC5xQCM7bjQiMTQiIgojPjNOOUAxNW98UiIxMiIqXip0dHQqfisrJQojPXwKcHJpbnQoKDEvMmFuZCA5IG9yIDEzKS0oMGFuZCs0KV4xPDw2NT4+NjIpOyMzNSg5OTk5OSsrKysrISkgPSM7cHJpbnQoMTcpCiMgICAgICAgfm5KPAojCiMbZ2c5OWRkaTIbYCB8MXwxKzY=&input=), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Jcu9CoMwFEDhPa/gcptLITG0ev1JCUZx7tChcxFbBHHRVkKn4Kvbit92hrPityUN3HLQ0St@wPlTYzFmnDLOGVbpzdSUT/7OKeFhEzrnwkWpI8PSs/c8jE4IipLn2IGBaQZK5UnE/1SZbMhanVeVTmSBaS7MRm0OEkos9p0ukiHslvFqGTIM@t6YrhuSoAVPnpRe1x8), and `a partridge` in [A Pear Tree](http://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree).

The existing code pretty much cancels itself out in Prelude, consisting only of while loops with falsey arguments and some stack manipulation on stacks we don't care about. Even better, there's a spot in the code that's a comment in all the languages that have them (between the `#` and `=#` of the previous submission). The hard part of fitting Prelude into this was generating numbers with only one stack and without blowing up the byte count. This program uses a loop that adds 45 to every stack element and outputs it as ASCII, thus by placing a 5 above a 3 on the stack, we get `20` as output. (Neatly, 20 is an easier number to output than 19 is in Prelude, so answer 19 being posted actually helped me a bit.)

Comment: Prelude should be fairly easy to work into future programs. Some advice for anyone it may happen to cause trouble to: don't let parentheses line up vertically; make sure you don't allow exclamation marks outside parentheses; and once you've placed digits outside parentheses, don't place more parentheses further right on the same line. The gap which I put the Prelude program into is still open, and looks like it might be a fruitful place for other 1D languages to go (Prelude's sort-of 1½D, and acts more like a 1D language in this program).

Comment: Nice, beat me to the punch with Prelude :) I actually think ASCII-only V might be possible with `:%s` replace, but even then it's a little tricky (and V is annoying to test)

Comment: If you use a `:` to start a command in vim, you're gonna need a carriage return, which also happens to be unprintable. :/

Comment: +10000000000 for `a partridge` in A Pear Tree. But does it print `5 GOLD` in RINGS?

Answer (score 25):

## 100. brainbool, 2953 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8ââââ(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>â
# 36!@â`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]4O6O@|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))â\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss 9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡


set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#defineâ x(d)â#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27""e ' Zing  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts(  "92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0â
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8âdggi2âM`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002953 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3042 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*.
**100** in brainbool

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvbcttIer42Km@wNy2QYwAkARCUKPEsaWx549nxSrHsccokbUMgSMICAQ4AipRlunKVqhwuklQuUkklm6QqVXuRt8htnmKfYN9g8v3d4EESJXlyqApkAg30393/uf@/u31mx8OffsrQxU5C/3LghwlL3Dhhvci7cCODfXvJDmwvLpe2JYlDRWFv4njBgCVDl3nBeJKwvue7seTYCWuxcdqLQQWWYZFr9wSY1A8jRk3Y6NxnHnPGY3bm20PDYb4H2GfFCnNH4UcPreJwRJCJG40jF/eYBa7bY/HYdby@5/ARmTtL3CD2wiA2mOecs6nn@6zn@miwQsMpoDM2idc@iUENqRdKDJczvoH08i3rAiZwF4S7YzvihIdszLmwoH8a2eMxkJQy7BSIJ97IjZmXKDFz7dgjbqJJ7AY9zrPxks8hs4N1KtmFZzMb@E4i3nfsRgnIM3i/bOhGLrq0afBBZI@YOo28BCwglh6yE9eO2KvIdTWMAlG4sWOPgce1ITFYSCMkRIjBRdZoKEfHzxSITrQw7HEiZaLtV3/0nWQzo8my7@v4NWW5Lh39@im7ynaoDCzQGcQ7jlRbY80vLDY7HRe/mXVmDqK5hF4lcMVnZjhOTFsfA0E9AYKmTUUq6RclY@yvDcwaN2SxplACqgdpsOcB@6HAKXMmUeQCjxVT7XMQ7YfBAPwEsdEkIH4EbLcIEThh0IsLzL0A18JAyCiccg6/GnoQWkwisc/AINsh3gtj4AyFOUD3Uo4uxo1Df8Lh0DJOSAHBFTSlHp/32Q@sb3s@NUE9dSWwjtx44ifUZhL0SPIjL3B7Blug4YQ9AhqFFxjORqf8A@xntGZ1HCkAQxAhJ5WqfvdX/9AbDNDPoeOEUS9V1x9YL3QmIyBsc2RtqCIpbBjYPkcLcAUaXTTHABe27/XshIYPLtMhOBJ81Gk48XssxIDR1INpDe0LmGO/7zqJK5Q8nCTAscBG9rnwFZ7QXBA@ss8gWD4AH5uTrbODJ5CS4wqV0UeTpF9h@viIKbH5Tt2vqftbHRe4aYaWy5rmoA59M3L8E96U@xTnh8OVPEl7Xnkh2ZE/Hk7gNVATxGP4k4iY6dggJya3ksD/FdgZZzT3RVB1bqRTV4lcdgbLXhDGdUToALXXyXLTHlYyXcBdVzG3t6Zh0E4oWRLfchN@OMXAHDdyotDpgAa3BzaGSlKCDgVBYkT@5Tpp5wE0nXo7c1lFP/MgHdIDOJtUGGs0Any7JGDQm5DemlGM7Ev04ggnvZIk8/oQ8gh6G10yxyVjgFW4wtPRIBOuGLEHPQr7rKiXyuUHhJ9E5qH@Ft7jk3mvjIn4G2I@ZH13ynw7GEzsARQ5DNDEdhx3nKQWBEriBDZy0xHyj3rq1Y14KGUPbo7NvVvq79fGIO8jpJf6aJvUHowagdW6DytndjTglsh6XgR78S9vjg6AixuDyx8I5BoCH@Q7UFhMTVAyd@Y6kwTmBkWeDj1nCN0l7AJhsMI73hwen9ZHh8vR@8uhCRmr9bgkGebyE6FxZxc6SfR2P/D61FXr2gcu/PUP9/dsx6MNHYdLFOGh1r4apm1A91KmYT4/pVgC7m8xeXPLWgYYS36Cwd/RxBS5P04gMOizNwgIxA6WE/@aZ/TiQMFU4cUeuE5TOOn6q@fHNB@8cUUUA76LuWzdmYeIadA8naKpYiEEyXWGIdMDpqQ4qDKfUT8CLTOOHF7Q18IIWTPAJ5X4xasWHX0UMdrNCZW1bsPxIZUCa8tyt4A5zI@hQsHE9/EyCbiJqa52BV1z3Dg2YDDgrUHxCLCT8642vw6YDKNwyty5Vlc2DfczBfJkcubN/h9KxCG8xB1UrYmBf/oaOdwCXAhCllPW3YLgvHsSjsjPszecYsL32whzQx/zgTS@TIbwdLrDZLsZjl2gdM2TKMATQbqq1XlIpyjGx9AL1Ctla2tLqSktpYDSPkoNKu1TKY/SPi/pvERwBpV4iwIvUW2bt6BvXWXeXvQ807ok2hnFrZ@8sWq3a7XtbsFuW@mzRE8NkwnmDkDr9EA/itZsUlHT5NYUhBpnfUmQ/wrC@R4hH/veo5m4jwBxlTpIy8E6kiyYsX3dl8qrmpKIVi/MEdhnjC83RxHyele8AQK485B0dFV6XzSs8rUukPfcbtn34iG/XQO9hdbtGt46Hp31@W0DQC0NAxBTUJZEfOGujCKRMITmTznYKAxCgQr45QW2@ZI/DMwem/C57qSvIXPmwuYHrnnmBVR@AEyvVjhk/@zMuwsUfCHUF88NYNHkbBPbEJ4Nb83j7Brjk0mU@G4vff7nn/QggNviGdqXMQL682XhPfhGotL7d0orbUov/LZZsh8nPtK9B/pwbAribX9Z2NxXjb10of6QbMCzPGDqgzaKcODqbus3TMOf9NzFc3OnnIfXwwHROvBGXHJ4UmzDPc8dzW8EM6I9JT2RH9o9UySinrsSpWC6O7MHYXBprs1qRnT2FTgu4g22yjyT4SSZiDslmw8JzRvT7z5jTCGLZfvMcs0wts@8OzhISOzepbTCFshN633fPhfF91TcTKogJvIGyGwXz7vAEO0hIB/bjmtO@eNO/xFM4jEXJi/d01/ki/tdIF7gYGYNVoW7AEGmz28/R@W4IjiwA0KVFnv0NRZ5N5jq22eXNJUNf77@0ICDfJ7p8B1NJ58vbjM9XOViq2Wl8fju9o6Ttq9WN7cWK1C8AydE2uw@NB9hUvFGtq@XemvFO/3rYupflTa5H/vCRlDg2zEUJEnZ7F5ALPx2n9LSPOFMfDtale5R2RU6i5T7rqxt1WbsOaHvpZq5eNkwQEBh3s2QaNUNrSvy26opvaUu8ymiHpp4v9zrN0MnoWTpDtX5Co8k8hTKBNd0wQjvYpcTTul3p8EOwwtX3DdPQZ82YvUVHkf3uTIg1r7dvOc8pKG0DsRvmz3h@UasEsff@L3GXoRhhEQ1ZiWjeK94Nqpx7PlhzE75/T5eIEWPY3HfrMDrbPPsQHeGwqyW5c3NNiLFZzR2yO93CNf2B6G/WxmYNm53asAk6pNjT59f69SWTsmyHnRKy/AlDKz0eac3P8e/h5SDFkDgvj2KY5bFzYpypwdLI/67CUSYTwtem4l7VqwsNSuK3XtVqsYOI2c4tS/vhXpo5riLzYuZo0aL9TwQ/p8Ns3P/ML2v81K3ut27v9tr4j33Xbhpfr8lVFYqWj@zhVUsfr3P6vsTd@Ju9CHHZx9dKM5XB8X3IlVMyaixT@f@vX1@Fdo0i9PbvT7H9j3Y@YMxTI2dIIg@CR9IAAbBZHxNluvZwyR4@YBNPAnD3s/X1KXXqTwcCtXYqZs8gMXRKERyGo4QEgRfIdk0VOfbiuJ@TbL8y6rnj94TxBPRvf0uF3oQjCK4gLC881hH9LKRr6kjKd2P6jJVqVaRUwVuckn3u6x2k4c8C8MNIRtfG3nJN8CWK9JxId25wzcvSvdp4uVmaOZ54EQuX59erLixDK2aT0YI85IwMhiHU1U7n9c0STSisGEQAGwBxbejaEdA7HTFDPFbwmG9Pmu3WfZqVivWrDlrMrkms25X9MrXpo9mY76P9FI0bWftbjOr6LqSVTpBjRUVDur68OIbQe1rcH2PPwSeK9JZYI/4JgSVF5TWxU4Hgiva3hraQQ@J7evA44uJThiJ9XqxKfSKVg3@47e9dNdv4ILIkRfDZAcB7VSHI3cYTvfFuOnoh@OxTbuG1AdyKV8sN@pPDlk89RJnKDb7EPu9fvaqku7UpPvneDkhNVnDQggVVX3gYCdCaAKbXugKfUsHXrZaEIWAejIK2NTrJcPYQKQUOC7fCVrsTgCTiMCCJApJXwvsOeu5lNjx1dKPE8jWD8NzvkhLmPzHb8X@FCo9UiEqL4bnG6ZrIzI4OItvCjlOOAHWi04@uVGYgqjEZKQFEzIzWIsrvmvMGdp84wyaqC@2jWgYsXX05PCU6UdMoQ1/2kWqe301e/jylz@0i93mFzYy3f/8E5MWrjnf5G/0PSuWC2wBUp@TXq1XF1G9qlWYnJ3JKVm0tcx3UpdKJayJqVTm4lpsA434rjTXO3fKt4H4Xl9AWQ9t9wYx7AOvGu9aGE0zq058b@QlTD9NWJlORcA92iiJfWxG5wxoS4OaZGfsMxuSrugOs8pFvAmG@LSLNmp@u1hz215fGzWfumcTvo5wUTJK201OTvZ9s9HipcjthbTP2n7XmXbNeMGVTmf2TbE0A9vCCOCPTbKco18/vcoareLnzzECJ1meK3W@dk3mnb06eX5ydPrq8NXrU7BxLqjMPAujkb1yEaQEYx8R7TD0@cY1@BF5bvyw23jE/Yb0KAVUVZa1WQNxBIOHerR0LClbZV3OiqKo455kWXejMnUffY@lro6dcGmnglXidTdXWCgAMQ82OYFfXSAPxbna4K44OTJrgiAdBHHwJcLLt02EXa/l8ILh@/QOpqdkrENxUldQm4GIVgGc4i1gBJIbiZj/L2E@xjzyMOYE9RDmAJYeGn1t4GeHz79//fLo9thrw6Ywt0CWGrJ2VuhohkwEfrDPNZz2oxd6E6bnCRaOAX5/KDa5bH/l2uLlfhVpUp8csw/bJqPgq3kxGTcjP2KwQz@GI@314BnOLhNyLPCoYotquU8lZ8AAYznPFZgsEWzcvL2vDMcxRczmfBCNsxyO9xxvOprRcc3f/dU/iOMYnQTlP0vLfZT/UpTfmcSg2/v3Ascla4gtPzw/YTFmK0H4yJ6t0UQTBk1IXoB43xuBgxecIQQukF3Ru@pHbf8AfkIIYCZ5PnJ2fDw36qrDJBnXTJPmdyTefYMv8LszyAG@0kCqav44odMx8M/mbnl3xzKBpH6x6JBvug5o0Vl0qGk1qJB04Y2bH84c1mg0mBwjTnSbu3XBSDNrv9uWPywRzQJWEqFAm6ENmqxaoK6VNlOzdt7SqClZoWIprFvHLC/kgolC5QWAaPQ5SPkhYyYKU1bR/q07S7hTvVyEOIgvgpCNiE/8jNSiIx0dib41Wbqlu6vFZdpUW9NmY10M8hsCOyWwmrxJdRg05J83aE6A8p@LcrtT1L90N53vWerO4e1jPOrNQzhECzs4DULabHgGXJlaMkvbprWrrdmJnHYFbMkqPqNL2AHsynG9j@E4Pnxy9Py745PTW8dQOKRyE0xhSquR7@hGod1dFpQbOr9g6bfPzNMX3z5bMHIdq1WkTxCrcP8mmptGu4npHaO/Eev6t8fmFbcGsopf2zHfhNaf8Tz3du@rWnMN8IlYhLw1qqpdzdvdRqsTZG4N/3nTobGMkaNzYih1Yn5kTGEbPM7zxW7Fq/Ac@nLPaRg9IQjv0/q5mMVeBx06KbXMnnth0ikJyVjtgshZtXENW02c3BE8WAwPx5F@yVoyxl2N5Ui3VpTXEREpdrjE5FrLJbOJ5mOR6vGDb3aAKD/yHAEdc28rEkJ@SgspwfNklUUgM6F1FJ4sXfLEAHa/XKHteXzx3o4uUwqWNafuyNNfLfAhL7A6igCvFEYJ8pF46HtndbvZnrHlRv19pxSMeOx7iUrHA2YGJVygRtWIAKvhu3S6oFHtpkcZ2OLEQZ4fWjiZgF8n4Zitktyn7qL0EnkOezpB59AAl303GQGuzx8vXXL5Lvt1qKMx@KgskGhjFDWlwRj1yhjdGLqznjfAtKFqBXiYbyxrddzB1vJIThU4VcGqX9LS8zpjftYRjTWO2W3b8IKeO1OVqaLVusQdfFemby4UTb6lA/ycSHpopHfzwMjC9u0kNcLlYYub9l2tLu36utlUq8YwlugMBUJ1jHiaRN@jiAlR7Y/sMVMnAUUvMTMYf1U7alCIk0hjeosmpykLWD7Pg3w8eIXBeMs@L3k@nVJU6WyqajYhZ/oaBz16fPLGrG0ZRhdlPojGspSfP0HsQJmtJiEiRJMa7xazKf5qhNEU6QxhJJ5ZPqxEyXUEqI3V3JAHQ26A4AWnmrUes5UjWFmg4Gq1Wkulcd27VRnU4vbEYpjodoPXWoSP4G@6Vw6u0RlqOh2FtM2DQzn4lRsEsFcVOjOCdTJ7AiWLtMLiQH9heexyDcE/TLfeb87ZR8qVHyIyyZp1niDW55ieP3RYJ@n0OwHN0fVL8xemYdav1KzfvDQRVmktNTtsWvntXD6fDXJqNqDA4vFjyivnWcQt7w3ZkGcA0rO@VocyI85pZoN61m6o2V6zlOMt8JrPa1do8CU2jausPTezjxEmFPAlEqapZmONbKFoGNYc@JF5ZM0CFOZKlZk8o9OrNHzWy@cJByP7nhD4YnZO83yO6JyaPJOtp@GqORgtfMg1mfz0U8baRea0v7uthvul7a1chmUOZDPXefr27ZOLutK2@yXjx@7J@cnJH2sdVck8OZatHbnOcqaUMXPFz3um@eHDBwRyrN0yWkZXa@tKt6229vZy9cJuJVc4KFhKoZ5hvlW0LE0tlbTTzk5Q9zxvHPd6@IVDOt6GUKZGonmES7VOFKW8rZy@o2NZ@1v44/9wLV/pvsW/pJ85yO1rS2PqjzMp03oEXdre3Tp4BFTdPL9qtQMmZb5ImUsp86HxQcogXs20Wt35PK@3jTxsLq/nG@1Gw2i1Zi2922pLmSspM5tLmZJMTMpJmeas8ZJ31n7aEr3mfwTDv8ezoXfb45Pvjw5Pjwqlhp4pPTt8Uiidvv42Y@GtvHqlym16fXl0@PT49atCSbT65fMfjl6f4HvcbR0c5A1d1w@MVhdYzL7Jt/LNJEnY2/c5WMnT1uy1qTcw6PdS5iWH1DtAo6MBfud49/jgs5RpZ9rqfmm/VPSLF0Xr3Dp/ER4v/7EXx8eo8GbFj2FUHBaHVs@yrFnRfV28LF7OiqPw2Oqh6OKvOELRK/ZnxUExKAaWtd7RPf9Gx@GL4xBdhWiWzIoJ9Vrs4zk4Pn6BzvoY@CP@vGKREJwVL/Cv6Fv8evce@W6x05HaUNhueXdc2v2xzd1/udptuzMv6cqsoHTa1WpV6dYzZtzpmELr5RJUliDm8/fvnx6@Onz/3qTMdtbI5g/y@gGuZivfSB/7mV6LWGg0tjqSok7fvHlDvzfTi6ko8cKbKXuTXngz5b2KHIYHKeib1fPNFNfFHZ1cL7Brl6q2y92ruaZpjzpKXRGUqKqLkEaVrc6s1GclmUcKVbgKa5tmo92y1mrtlvG@W9F0tUi1O9o7q9FIq0paGMnKTA4jhV3NxZ96NW@o/NLoT9PoY3pvaSqqtTLeZlfqrKE2VPqGT9Tqat6iIoe7Qqmtal1tPhffcFe1huizpYFASs7@j/6FMYvHTMnMMzQ9BGynrCH1c7WdXbWSr6Z/zS0Qo8rbyjZolBVbabcPctu5vZ32fjfXzamNnJHrtLqz9UtTMgwqt9CappUh7kkZo/5StkqyQlpUpwXP0HcNH6nYdrWuqDlxsdzyqljVfC5/0M5Vq2K0XO7zlobm6FzGlYGmMZU1Wo2l@FeaoLXwu2Ipg1GeX0EjRB0mGDVdyex0ZsUih6@fNbNXGXte592zubyAThWLd68qdb7ELV/JWTtqW115LmevzuY0C@csjc@f5Z16PbcjynuVOty@lUtriqhJi6hwY9vhFgZPT5qkgMUaiGqeuQMvkDLja6qdL5fLZgn32Te7R6WZVKelYLHuLOuy0HRWqfIOM3HMqhICvTMIesr2igjkfd@OWNjvb4nviFiR@7sIGlzfp0UUCugQ1/i9KZKILSkDj4BwBtW4Rie2O3Hd6WQydZfXEy@u2R8/Ih/h1@9/83d/it9v8fsb8fybf6@W6f773/z1v/3un/5FwvMvfv@bv/3X3//mL/8ev39Mf39/8ydJRNoWK@8tCpb0ghYoqpbYrvHoM0qRW5X@EPSNJs6Qtte8hGZYxL1FySBulErVSrlS3S5VCpVqZads7ZbLBatUsPYqe9ViAZNrxdqtlKtWobJT3d7Z2akWmFUqV/ekjBv0vL5pYrKyZJnxAtIrOijZoCOloTFsYRrsuX1El4/YTO1pjzK9xQc2qTB5u9IpIqPjAbDKNHZFbldlMfIgoK4WCxN4m/L@pCLv7sm1HJ7yvryNIpf2TGVFBYopKx1Z1trV7r68V5ZrmNt15bG1z@S9KiLjvT1Zq8vuoCzLu6y0J8suAtm3JE0m1@fAesGOJT0MLtowGH66LlH9uCkwUuWqyrjIqx1ZGITQLkVVlL2SomhKHZ1syes6qdWJPFCXEofgFu61HrnJJArUqg4PwvSqVp8LNP5gDY/oHMG3HVEAzIdB9rtblekzQBpqlbpvlc9ytYKlFw4kod67lpSZSz06CLZTZfVqnWILuNxGS8oqhIqyLWX07XAnzGSzWcQmr1rytnxsNMw0zGiZPMboUNhBE76xiF9azJQilzYcevRfG8W8USkTLQMWZ/L/zcvACE30KdXJX8mZ1ENe0szXEQg1vmT4KSF2crVcxE7/20TtBXHXrp3yI7LtLtO@/NrzryrbeovnAUgG5wy8nY9Pq@/23lXevXh9/Pr42UGtUqvAiWXiz1pYtr4E39UztbGyvaNsI7ppZgRx1p6WaZX2jNi@zHTTbVF1Z09jeOMuqmRl@jQPL6fh29P0WmnD@/RixMM7IFL5RW8w8Eq/ePHhc9Y0FYUxK7v7RW@Ifw3cnhwLEavyblnWaDs5fvf@3fsMHBGTS2WoXd5EAG2af1yCWVeru5XdjPSTad63joPaZSbUd5EkTEabUqHDyHthU5oYLNMhFF5MPrnR0uoZmT1l@MPW9W/cFVz7xP9fLb5JhBe3DyrY0cAp8OV9lqMT0e0uXMJia0ilWtqd0JabGcKGWLEuNp2oC6@@LGIUMlskpUXxkTIf1WtadeY1qDM8kTClI9C1aJFvUpFWSTgWXlerS@u7NByTFlqv4bLWPp8X4HOBlqDHGfUE2aJu@Qr0RrSb7ahpa@0GQLvYpey7U1RSMr@GDGTN6rKHAvvZZNxoj9xQW9DEUVhVpt9XophLuaQwqktEdm5cl36lOtoV5az1L6PHj5134/aoW9dGzYSe@fwIju9c9QRILmmOmrpVHwPZetLO571uc6T9Sh1z5EfNIoAxNvUca1dLSQfNVFyxVvjUDvQvQbfwrB3krW5hUsi9bX4q2M1iYYYf2FbwCz@CeQtWqknzUz6o2w38KH2@xgk4/rxdv755hibnqt/81La7zaJW99Ewn38GYoBn3Pbz@a6GwX1U3m5Y9x8/tvN@a1b3dV0jqHfb@8/aCQrdfJPea6rdmO1/ak/Qvqbi2cQwvgbk0e66DNAf8KuDx0J8K9QFjjNCbwb0Rs1m7u1@7m2uubX1qT3TR92CYH@tuBI8IT8j5Nd1RM29XVcszhIeE6ryN17tGyMXM7kA7QOTC@O1lgLD3FvUjFfWMP8v)  Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c) *I can not test Archway2 because I don't have the proper C compiler, however stasoid has confirmed it works in archway2*

### Explanation

I can't believe we've made it to 100 languages.  I would just like to take the time to thank everyone thats been involved in this process.  Its been a fun ride and I hope to add a 100 more with you guys.

Brainbool has been in my eye for a while.  However since brainbool can only output two numbers, `1` and `0` I have not been able to add it until now (I wasn't around for 10 and 11).

Brainbool is just like brainfuck, except instead of wrapping at 256 it wraps at 2.  Brainbool also does not have a `-` because it is redundant with the `+`.  Our brainbool code to output 100 is fairly simple:

```
+.+..
```

In order to mask the outputs for brainfuck we add a loop and a minus:

```
+-[.+..]
```

Now all thats needed is to find a place for the code to go.  My place of choice was the first `+` at the top level of the brainfuck code on line 8.  To substitute in the plus we added our code and a `+-+` which acts as a `+` in brainfuck and a noop in brainbool.

```
+-[.+..]+-+
```

#### Cubix

I put my code before the Cubix capsule causing a mirror to move into the path of the pointer. In order to fix this I moved the capsule a couple of steps forward in front of the offending mirror and all was well.

Surprisingly nothing else broke not even the notoious incident.

Comment: Actually, brainbool can output aribtrary text. If you pass it the `-b` argument, it will build 1s and 0s into bytes and then outputs as characters.

Comment: @Phoenix Well, that would have been nice to know before I waited for 2 months to post this. :P No worries though, its in the polyglot now so all is good.

Comment: (Feature was implemented two days ago) https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44255?m=39076825#39076825

Comment: @WheatWizard I confirm that it works in Archway2.

Comment: Congrats! I notice the VIP score just dropped under 0.003 as well.

Comment: I have to confess, back when you originally posted about adding this for 100/101, I didn't actually think we'd ever get here. This is pretty dang cool.

Comment: @stasoid I'm working on getting Archway on TIO, just FYI.

Answer (score 24):

## 65. [ALGOL 68 (Genie)](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/algol.html), 1634 bytes

````
#16  "(}+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>.}+?
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsd4O6O@oh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.

#
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts(p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm 
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005949 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1710 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkufGL/SlDLINgCRepChLAkmLtqVZd9strSU/wiQtl8AiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzE/0ptZBb5Eyu6O2I1YSAIKqKzMrHxVZZZ@L@BFTiP/ZuhHGclYmpF@4l2zxCBPbsgh9dJ6tSZJHCqJ@mPXC4ckGzHihfE4IwPPZ6nk0oy0SJxjMbBBCiRhtC/ApEGUEBxCgiufeMSNY3Lp05HhEt/jsGkUYH/GkjhhcE9JyFifpDFzvYHncjqETTMWpl4Upgbx3Csy8Xyf9JkPA5bE3QogI@N05ZMgZUj9SCJwufEdVhdvRQYwIZtPl8U04dONSMznPp/1JKFxDExKBXIGjGdewFLiZUpKGE09lCEMSVnY55KKF9KNCA1XZ0muPUoo8DtOOO6UJRlMz@B4yYglDFBSJD5MaEDUSeJlIAIUZJucMpqQ84QxDaiAAljq0hj4WCMJxCKkkOFEDK6oRkM5OjlWQGFihEHjTCoktfN//VmixGiS4oUDf01ZdqSjX5@R22IX28AFIAOlxolKNdL8SlKz22XwN7UvzWEykwCrBFLxiRnFmQmYaZIBe8uWfl01Yn@FLGnc0cSKEQmoPuiCPA/JmwqflztOEgZcLEVKr2DKfhQOQZow1WQcojRCsmuBAtwo7KcVwq5BZlEoNBRNuHzPRx6oLEWF0EsQD3VR8sIBuDjBBcDycnnO6aaRP@ZwMDLN0PxAJjAUMT4fkDdkQD0fh0A/ohJcJywd@xmOGYd91HvghaxvkDkbbtRHoCC6BnIUkPIP4DPBiqdxpgAY1BDxqWLXP//6t/5wCHjarhsl/dxY35B@5I4DYJhyZikYIpprFFKfswVwFaQuhgOBa@p7fZoh@fAmJ8GZ4FQn0djvkwgIJhMPHGtEr8EZBwPmZkyYeDTOgMcKCeiViA@esFuYeEAvQbGcAKfNp62Tw6egJZcJg9GDcTbYI3p8RJTU/KA@PlAfP@gy4E0ztFLRNIcOWJtR4p/gTfmW4bxpL/WJ1nPuRehFfjwaQ8yAnjCNIZokKEyXwnRSDCoZxLwKueSC5pEIDJ276IQpCSOX4NfziXEbETaA43X02xzDUqdzuHUTY/0VCwPrBCPL0o0g4UcTIMx5w8AJNh0icTqkQCrLJ9QWExIU@Zf1qV2FYOmI7ZKRPf3SA@2gHUCoyZWxMkcAr1UFDGAT2ltxioDeABZXhOilJok3ACUHYLfJDXEZOgN4BRNxDomMuWGkHthRNCCWXq3Xv6P8LDHb@nuT6p/Nb@oYJ39HzW0yYBPi03A4pkMw5CiEIdR1WZzlHgQzSTPwkbthkH/U85hupCOpeHiXNo9tebRfoYHRR2gvj9AUzR4EFYCodR@8nNBkyD2R9L0E/MW/uUsdAK7vEJc/IsgaAx/le1iYL0xgZGzK3HEG7gaGPBl57ghsF7kLhcOK6HiXPHxapQ4hRx8sSCMzduthVTLMxSdk414UOmp0Ew9EfUTVWvvAlb/64duYaRpsQRwtWIQItfLVMKkBtpcLDVbzM9xJQPibL93csxbbi4U8QcA/48KUsN/GoDCwZ28YIggNF8v@SmT00lCBpcJLPZA6LuBo6@fPT3A9eMvEHgbkLtay1WAewY4GhucLNHbMlSAxdxQRPSRKzoMq8/X0E7BlponLG/rKJkLWDJCTivLiXXNEn8S@7O6CSlqbcJykUiEdWe5VYA3zUzChcOz78DIOuYupTLsFW3NZmhrgMCBbA3cjwJ1cZtpsHTAbJdGEsJnmKNvI/UmFPB1fetP/hxpxkS9xh1mtqIF/@iN62ACcK0KWc9FtQAjhnQN7L2DTQ154uBYNYIu03Drz3fYUN4ldSY5vslEU1tajibzsqYrd2hszgMXFiG@2r6PyKio@4KUXXkWoJTOYty4sw66voYDd/ubIgZeO@G0NdIOtzR4@Og0uB/y2BSBEK7hjbLwjiMJIEAcJeSE1X/GHARFzGwfrgWmN/BMGdj5k@n7NvPRC85IN7oM8fvLkOYcZXF569wGBGDCfmT@3gCXjy21Sgv3IaGPhImtyPh8nma/3zQyf7L//rQ/y3tTGiN6ksIO9WjQuQjZBzeiDe5WTD8UXftuuyE9jH7Kb7@BwKe5aqb9obMd1QF4xsHbYX4Q8qQFOfR98CEQGvr1pzuAJ/rjP5s/tSLkM19c/MTr0Ah1sedewuALhFdd03Fndh@XOIi7Q4GY/8SPaN0X65bGlRoXs2ZQOo/DGXInmRnL5B1idr7NkmW9lo3E2FndMsr6nOy/Gv2@5YA5p1dtP7KP8cQ88MLF7n@0Kt0kguujHPr0yL7F5MYDm9qmKySTeEDK6@fM@sLdnMXWZOUnxsdVsXsLuyIc8@ezX12en37QfjhC2TYkv7lvRPQ9dWE/C7PuYYJY@v/0Zw@N24FIfrK8mbA/LHPqKmLw7gvXp5Q3m5aM/b0NIdVguEz1aJh/LKkoc3z/IdbcPEnUWPs6NID1k31t1YOnwAphutb/SvNcmvEhfpjipMKQB5nRbYg@9pkR3fZqCaWS5dNk1aIPfvmWquEK4aDPL1rcM9Q5T8zTzvkxlOTL23AhW75irGV98eLlvUbu7DViiwfoZvy2H4ltur88Y7eNS@/WbBhu5GSYI95jMH4hGYm@O2c@KXRjRfUJzown@3bvEj6JrJu7bV6HPW7n6A9FG97lJwP5yc3jf/Z61vvVSiDVw2x4Fr7Zylbn@1u8YmqIEkrOUVA3rm@rZasxnxnPjhXFinJEzz4/Sb8oDUtM0FfftprwEvUw8Guou2vBqe/uwrYzxFY20@f0eBVN/GPm7e0OTwm0TSGxxX/FK3iK1Tit5ARK@eUlecEoXNd0CROaE8UR7njqQAqb/4wA8OIsSg3A4VaXlsqZJYhDawjAEsDkUr6thaUOU7FICTplxWG9AOh1SvJ0eWAf2jDSJfCCTXk9g5Un20TTmBbFXYminSHvNovLunVJUuuEBsRQOyiC32g5K1@AGHn8IPpdTJyENeDUF2/OZOqJkAx6DdboRDfuwU3kdejwrcqNEFB5EdYvvCv/x935evhwymGTgpdQHQWDBPQrYKJo8FnRz6u04plj@RBywNvoib9Kftkk68TJ3JKqW4NCvj8/38pJTXvyHl1PcoqxwIZQKXQPggWZCaYKbfsSEH@SEF6Pmk4IoOQ5CMvH62Sg1wPRDl/GS1rzMApwkCBZmSYR@VCHPSZ/hos3Tvk9j0K0fRVc820RO/vF3UWiDTg9NCNtz8rzyu0KRgJfYvLrlutEYuJ4j@cySKAdRUcgQ68cgkRvwYia@a8QdUV4BBEvU5/UvJCNqYE/bZ0Q/IgqeW2A5zPEGarH96i9vOlav@ZUEJmzgTczAudzkn/RHdipXyBzEmaFdrXZb0L3sVYhcnMr5tLBGzkvCC6MS3kRUbHN1zetZAS@vc7tjE17P4kXLEJcyrFtDep1m8Kpx1MJpmkUVdv4BZNL6WUbqeLjDQCTQEgV5gsclWJvBIcUp@UJGaCu6S@y6BW9CID6WA4PmMt9aTXHNZ@xyzDeG11WjWmvy6RQvmo0WbyWsH2HBuPOhO@mZ6Vwq3e70J6s6BbFFCYA/NNFzjn59dls0WtaXLym9gbx7pjg8CUf3Lt6ePj89Ojtvn78@AzHOxCwLx1ES0GWIQCOIfdiAjiKfV@BBHonH0u@HjUXoyAUnv3snF0U7jwEkD1TklOsqV4uSrgapylx9OHXwqDFExTlpUPvtlmDDmZFJE9h5B@ysM7N4y5GoKilS0iC2RTRtvZfDC3E9houAyFbYn1885C2htgPhXAVwzreAEUxuncTsf4nz0/bZ2fc5R6jvcQ7A0veorxA@bj9/sUl4hSYCbPTnCwM8lkeVR1PYX0L8GnDLxIL43GKi/EBj7tAQr0eiykb9ZUhKFwUztKEBBlQffBKNmadWKTolQf83SNtPIQD2@@DRlzcZBgSIhKJGtiiUyQWYurFYnypElhA2bW4WtsHhJ5BOuB/F4CKH45jTbWdDXWb@869/E@dB3Qza/563B9D@T9H@YKKANg8QBI8L0aBY3jw/JSmsMmLiAZ2uzAkDPS4kXjhmxAtAgtdcIAgumF3Od4lH7bwBeYISQJgYsTBIcXos6amjLIsPTBPXZdgBDQxecGFT0APEOMONAvO3MR7PQVw1d@u7Ozbk80y/niPkVd8hZv8CoaYdgP1I117c/HjpkkajQeQU0kfW3HWEIM0i/VCTPy4YLQKsJJbwDoExMGQ5Avpa@TC1SMu2hkPR/xRbIT0HVmehFwjwKm8AiIafw1weMqwgUS4qLCCzacaD4c18awL7gjAiAcqJH9LOEemASODWZGnDdoFf6OEpvre2JzRW1SC/RTBeEDiQt5kOAQv5ry2WE0L7P0S707X0r71tB4wL22lvniOqd08BcS7k8CyMsOpzDLwStWpWa6a9q634iZyjAm7RK74ASvAD8CuXeZ@iOG0/PXr@88np2cY5GIdU7oIpRGk1yl3dqHR6i4Zyx@bnIn1ybJ69fHI8F@QqV3nXXa62Ib/L2D3E3opyyiYp3rFByLb@KOJlnrd1IssscAXwqUgAN6iq2u2s02u0umFhg/yXbYfUBaOE59LQ6qb8iFohWwLMomB0Hl2BeXzj9E3PEML7vHoO5@Wj8ZCr2jL77NrEUxnJMOc9sDaqjTVuNXFSKGQwJw9xIv9StGWgu6TlShvZ/Coj82LPgt7qyM3pzpcZ8NO8uAmuj//sgcc4sC3zgJPDX1gYshuiQhQLKAQHOoYkO9Eq8/82qizOh1e0@S95rfSubx8pt34EEaxoOnwD6MzAjT92STfrDroh@rJzY/5oGqZzqxb95o0J4VdrqcVR0y7XSuVyMSypxRAD0MOHuG@cFSG@XRiyIU8BSC/6mgOrKsTDZjF0irShFvvNaomPgFfIJW9hwNfUNG6LdGYWH0I4qcCXhGHUZmox1XB/aBmGPQP@PkVeWDQrAY1vVZnIUzxmR/JFr1xGHoziBTLw1eyelblxdc9MvlN18mXNHAYOj/7Kuo3@/nvB3iVEVmflx9Xag0NNV2XTLHWfXTtKhw6qxm@906vT03dK4emJJts7shPuSAWzZH15ZJofP36EQE9IR1d6nQdq69GjUsXZ3StVDh3Frhza1g8/2LamVqva2Q8/qDY5VZR6TTn7oPwmFVo/gGpruw8Of/goFaTCRasMl9EygA@p8LEBHxu92YyUG52G0WrpvVZHKtxKhc8zhG5OG68Qvtx5xsfBVd9/AfeG3uvEpy@O2mdHlWpDL1SfnVSqZ6@fFGx4qS/esKsGb6@O2s9OXp9XqmLIX56/OXp9etx@6nlenPb7aX/nZPfkMBr1WoeHZUPX9UOj1QNGpj@VW@VmlmXk/UUJbPRZa/ra1BvAwAup8IpD6l0NYL9IhU6hoz6uPq5avnVtTe0r@@pldLL8PTmBDm9qfYoSa2SN7L5t21OLvbZuptaNFUQndh@eDH6sAJqeNZhaQyu0Qttew3P/b3ASvTyJAFUEw7KplSFWawDP4cnJS0A2AMKf4MezLAv4m1rX8Gv5Nr8@XFiWJsHGulffjau7v3WwfELq@70Om3pZTyYVpdvBZb5gpt2uKYxMroKhYP9sdnHxrH3evrgwUW@FwrRRLB@W9UO4mq1yI388LvRbKDUDooKkqKoadxWHNqnDU@winpJ07F65eEsPxjMMEiW7pHH/rluOU2rn7R1o5809x2EpdTkTjiK4UlV2TX1VtrvT6qAqa7h12wcns2tg9Ra@7Wgf7EZD3a1rrdZuVYsSWZnKUaLczsSPejtrqPzS8EfT8GN@b2m3agNAAEbjrwIeoCZv377Fv7eT64lo8Yb49nbRufqCF@ybyYgSpTArYMgLyU5dg20P03Z21b3yfv7TfKABO7JS0/BHVqS5wJt2AbmXCobzSrar0APidzD1jnxm@LC5qO1LMlxS85INvVBqtG7DvlRIUwZXcErZmLHJeDxhi@uplx7QT59oDCuY6RgYvKvV/b363n6tulfZ29/bqdu79XrFrlbsR3uP9q2Kbdl79u5efd@u7O3s13Z2dvaht77/yCxJhT4bYGUgJimsC9FAiRXdfizX9iDVrT0CxmHtwEO4Bh5XRsaoJeFRM1GJdos2qMaaMwM0ohqxa0uFmdTHUvjOvoOhYtZoSUUFhyg1qaDXop2oUCwWIa6ct@SafGKkUpPBhEECBRkHF9IvUd3@Gv7sFA5ipbaj1LrNgsCu2o@0Qqv6yIBcv9ATH9Ud@NYrcHOr2gUy9f6vfiG7GExWTGbdjLY0ltfCnjasa6W15X1yHeB/XKVpuvdjfzj0qj9@/AJ7FaIo1Toh9i4awFe9IX4bcHv39ERIRd6ty1oh/XDx4aIKxrG/v1v4HQZ@Y2cDvYslfsBg9RsH29b4duK9pJhKhot1Hhovx7ClWJgKQVvxvUs0lrVvwn5WP/H/a4VvEvKFVqJiAyKNW@H5LSnxqNPTyO28KqJiLybm2iKPT1g2TkJiOaLegig8Z9EEKmjapIkAPPmGaKN6TdshXgORwRN2AjkFvOYjyk1s@ixUORdeT3Ok1QIF56QFo1d4WRlfLgvwmWBLzMcN@mLaom/xCuwFWIZ11Xy0dgegY/UARulaSj7NPzIN2K@qCwwV8qencWc8bHq0@Zw4C8vO/PtSFTOplFUCR8Jpl2JH@kV1tVvcjDlfg4cP3Q9xJ@g5WtDM8FkuB85MulI9AVLKmkFTt50YmHWyTrns9ZqB9osac@aDpgXAQBsxp9rtQtNhM1dXqlU@d0L9a9irHHfCst2rjCul983PFdq0KlP4A7FV/MpvILy5KNWs@bkcOrQBf7gvXJNE3EzL1FmvG8GQK9Vvfu7QXtPSHB8GlsvHMBngM@345XJPA@I@dG4OdPyHD2nZb00dX9c1hPpQe3zcyaDRKzfx/UCljenjz50xjD9Q4dkEMr4GzMO4dR0APuDPARkL9S1ZFzxOkb0psBc0m6X3j0vvS80HDz53pnrQqwjxH1hLxSPzU2R@1UbU0vtVw@Ii4WVZVf7JO/jJKKVEroD1gZAr8cpIwWHpPfTES2@Y/Q8)

### Rundown

This program prints **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 6 languages have to be tested locally.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).

### ALGOL 68

ALGOL is probably the least known of the four high-level programming languages from the early days of programming - the remaining languages of this nebulous distinction being COBOL, FORTRAN, and Lisp. ALGOL was better known in academic and mathematic circles at the time, but is today best known for its huge influence on modern languages. In fact most modern, practical languages can be described as “Algol-like,” not the least of which is C, which of course has its own lineage of influences and derivatives.

I’m pretty excited to include ALGOL because it’s another major stepping stone in computer history that we get to add to this monument we call a polyglot. That’s cool stuff.

ALGOL68 is the latest of the three major ALGOL specifications, the others being ALGOL60 and ALGOL58. Interestingly, the specification doesn’t have a fixed syntax, meaning that the tokens are defined, but not the spellings. This makes the language highly interpreter dependent because any given interpreter may use a different symbol to initiate a comment block for example. The specification describes the `¢` as initiating a comment block. But because `¢` isn’t among the base 127 ascii codes it understandably doesn’t see much use as the comment indicator among the available interpreters. Well it turns out that the Genie interpreter spells `¢` as `#`, which is all the opening we need to get past character 1 and make a polyglot.

Genie in fact has three comment syntax options, the other two being `co` and `comment`, both of which are specified as being written in bold. Yeah, bold. If we use italics, well that’s a variable. Genie solved that for us again by spelling bold in all caps. And since `CO` isn’t in the polyglot anywhere, we’ve got an easy method of hiding the polyglot from the parser. If down the road `CO` is needed for a language, we can switch to the more verbose `COMMENT` syntax.

There are no line comments in ALGOL - they’re all block style, which means they need to be terminated. Given the initial state of the polyglot, our ALGOL block comment is opened immediately and is terminated near the end of line 1 because Turtlèd is similarly using `#` as a jump token. Turtlèd very fortunately doesn’t have a problem walking through the `C` and `O` characters so in line 1 we can just insert `CO` immediately after the second `#` to initiate a fat block comment for ALGOL68.

From here we just have to place `COprint("65")` somewhere. I chose the last line because I preferred to finish out the line with another `#` comment and I didn’t want the comment to terminate at the `#` at the beginning of the last line. So we follow up our ALGOL print statement with `#s` and a `#` as the last character in the polyglot. The `s` in `#s` is for alphuck to balance out the `p` in print.

Thanks to @ais523 for opening up the end of the polyglot with answer 59 and making all this possible.

### SMBF

We added a different character to the end of the polyglot to terminate ALGOL’s final comment, and SMBF was previously reading the last character for its answer. To remedy this, I had to change SMBF to read the second to last character by changing this code on line 8 `[.>-]` to this `[<.>>-]`. This is an SMBF private code block since BF’s MP is at 0 when the loop is initiated.

### Trigger

At this point, I noticed some weird behavior with SMBF and it had to do with the relationships between these code segments ad the end of the polyglot.

•   Incident’s jump destination: `^_^_`

•   Trigger’s Jump destination plus answer: `X222999`

•   ALGOL68’s answer: `COprint("65")#s`

ALGOL’s answer tokenized a couple Incident tokens within its code segment, so ALGOL’s code had to go prior to Incident’s code segment. ALGOL also caused a prelude alignment issue if it went first in the order so it had to go second or third. SMBF meanwhile had an inexplicable failure when Incident’s code went last, so Incident had to go first or second. Well, I realized this was an introductory logic problem that appeared unsolvable, so I set out to make the inexplicable more… plicable.

After walking through SMBF I found that the problem with having ^_^_ at the end was due to Wise. Wise’s code ( `~-<~-<~-<<<~-`) isn’t hidden behind a non-executing loop, unlike most of the polyglot. But there’s no SMBF print codes involved in Wise’s code. It was just changing memory values. It seemed innocuous. So what was the problem then? It was that darn SM in front of the BF.

Wise’s code is changing the characters in the code about to be executed, and can you guess what the ascii value neighbor of `^` is? It’s `]`. Wise was putting a SMBF loop terminator at the end of the polyglot, causing SMBF to fall into an infinite loop. That’s bad mojo.

After some thought I took the 0 byte solution to the problem and separated Trigger’s jump destination (`X`) from its answer (`222999`) and ended the polyglot thusly:  `~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#`. This only works because no character appears consecutively following Trigger’s jump that isn’t Trigger’s answer.

### Wrapping up

That's all the major changes this round. I did make a minor change to cut the much discussed `c` in line 1, but that's it for purely golfing changes.

Good Luck!

### Incident Report

`#<q>"3"O.s` became `#<T>"3"O.s` because detokenizing `T` instead of `q` was more efficient at balancing

`<>{` became `<>{nd` to detokenize  `nd` and `{␊`

Put a space between `}}` and `+` in `#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[`  to detokenize `}}+` more cheaply.

Answer (score 22):

## 27. [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 235 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::  (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<65>>62)#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#3]#echo 21#===2|/=1/24=x=90/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6$//''25  #>say 27#"26
```

␛ represents a literal ESC character, as usual.

This program prints [**27** in Perl 6](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**26** in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), **19** in Reng (tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**9** in Perl 5](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**7** in Japt](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw),
[**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/Q5fCBajcC9y6O26SxlZmBAUagSqClVEIJlKgqkpVXT4VA//Qt/4jHmpyRpXTm5earkqoodFEUAIpZP@CqtZKsFBjSO1dR1sUA61nf97MhSYZhuBLoh/a2vJfEciXwUWBd1lF8HvZtr9T22HwoSU8nfmOpm3YDOXQHoFRfq/kvrV5TWbosBMcaK@vUMsn/8xfa49@IFhrTZ9y@vnfAhN57jsaTYetPPp8bgcvJZrfb86SGSNFdGjOdcgaA4bv5AV6gZDeOZw), and (as it's Christmas) `a partridge` in [A Pear Tree](http://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree).

The syntax highlighting that Stack Exchange produces for this answer is completely wrong. `` #`< `` is one of Perl 6's many multiline comment markers, and ends at `#>`, thus the only code that actually runs in Perl 6 is the very simple `say 27`. I chose this particular comment marker because `<>` aren't a matching pair in most languages, and thus the unmatched `<` won't break languages, such as Retina, that attempt to parse it.

I'm not entirely sure how the Hexagony works any more. When it broke, I changed one of the characters it was using from a `+` to a `0` to see if it was being hit; turns out it was, and turns out this fixed the program, but I'm not sure why (I know it broke due to a `#` in the line of execution, but it's unclear why removing the `+` fixes things). (The character in question is also parsed by Thutu, but luckily this doesn't make a difference to the functioning of the Thutu program, as at that point in the program, anything that isn't preceded by an `=` is copied literally into the working string.) Note that the `0and+4` from a previous line became `0and 4`, to make it one character shorter from Hexagony's point of view (Hexagony doesn't see spaces); this is to compensate for the `#|` on a previous line becoming `` #`<`| ``, which is one character longer from Hexagony's point of view (because it doesn't see backquotes either). Note that the code's now only five bytes away from expanding the Hexagony side length and breaking everything about the current Hexagony code. I'd recommend doing this anyway and just redoing the Hexagony section of the code; it'll probably be easier, rather than harder, to fit everything in after an expansion.

Some other languages changed too, mostly to add enough robustness that I could fit arbitrary code in on the last line. `$//` is a comment marker in Japt that allows spaces later on the line, making the added program less fragile in Japt (meanwhile, `//` breaks if there are any closing parentheses later on the line, and space is a sort of closing parenthesis in Japt). A pair of spaces is a comment marker in Pip, meaning that the Pip code can be substantially simplified here. This also means that we can simplify the 05AB1E down to a trivial `"26`. Retina needs the fifth line to be a legal regex that's good at matching things (the trailing `|` is thus for Retina); it parses differently from the corresponding line in the previous entry, but in a way that's just as suitable. The Cardinal is also very slightly simpler than in previous entries, but this is just pure coincidence with how everything lines up vertically, and the change is to code that didn't do anything anyway.

Assuming you redo the Hexagony (you'll probably have to), there are safe places to add code on all of the last three lines: the `3` in `#3]#` is only for Hexagony (and easily changed); the space between the `#` and `"` on the final line is ignored by the vast majority of languages; and nothing's really parsing the end of the fifth line other than Retina. (There are plenty of other places where code can be added, too, but these are probably the most convenient.)

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this answer and noticed I downvoted when i noticed my rep's gone down by 1. Can you edit the answer so I can upvote? :D

Comment: @betseg: I added a bit more discussion of the Hexagony, just for you.

Comment: Congrats on the bounty! I wanted to get this post moving again :P

Comment: I'd been planning to continue it for ages, it was just a case of trying to find the time. (I'd actually made a failed attempt at Perl 6 a while back, earlier in the chain, and didn't post it because it didn't work. Luckily, I learned from the mistakes and it works this time.)

Answer (score 22):

## 35. [INTERCAL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/INTERCAL) (C-INTERCAL), 631 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::Q):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#= >␉1#v#v0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#[␉
#`<`|
print((eval(" 1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or' (\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"␉*
""""#//
=begin␉//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#␉
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/ (\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE) a
#   +/Jn~
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>#>27.say# =#print(17)#$nd^_^_.]Q222999/+23!@1#"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVjLcuPGFV0Lv@BNG4CHgEi8qJHsEUWONGONa5yxLY80SqpEPZpAk@wR0KDxEMnSo7JNKovss8ky/5FtviI/4pxukBIpUXYoEWg0uu@9fe6bvxryQw7SeDqI04IULC9IlPErlrnkzZTsUp5vNjesUcYTmk0JLYthmtkNsvt2SEXINE1tz9KoDLkYkGLICBejsiB9HrNcC2lBOmQ0I@/KATFIxmhULdP6aUbkFpJcxoQT9TFIniZysmDZKGO45kQwFpF8xELe56EiTtikYCLnqci1KNXkxnD0iNX9k8mwRtyLy0Y0U@KmZKRkn0s9zuhoBH6aQQ4hQ8ETlhNe1HLCaM4lONiSMxGpk47uYUsJFYsCkytOCcU5ykzRzllWQFJX0SVDljGQpJL5IKMJscYZL3AaCcQeOWA0I0cZYza4AECWh3QEOZZYglkqORTyIK4Cementv/TuxoAr3a4dFRoRrZx9PP3GiVum5jnLXzbut7S9n/8llybXTmGFCAGpYwyi9qkfUdyr9tl@E6CnjfIbjVQ1YBKTLx0VHigTLMC4j2MnKumO4oX2JKdR5pYMIJqVQRdkPeCHDfUucIyyxikeICUXuLIcSoGQBNHzUoh0RBky4cCwlREeYOwK2CWikpD6VjhezTkUFkuFUJ7gIeGEvnKshWcsG0Y0QzPOd88jUu1DjvzgsexBBhbJcX3fXJM@pTHcgveS1KV1BnLy7iQe0oRSb0nXLDIJXMxwjSSi5L0CuwoiKoJ2Hyy4ClKKCyGGlJ1VPnqv3//RzQYgM5eGKZZNDPWYxKlYZlAYKqEpTBEaa6poLESC@saknu1HQyuaMwjWkj2YjpjoYRQXMdpGUckBcNszHNGhvQKftXvs7BglYmnZQEZGyShl5V/88pucfCE9qBYxUDxxrGVkThJWfS/Ic5on9Ry78x6vW29/rLLII/t2uum5w1asDB3XU3hqfZbxnK896BDTZrMHumzMYmpGJR0gGOlAhtoGLJRMcMTuOQFEHvsFGrSmXm4mw81c/cxZ2XpM99f4CFtsfK@mb9SCUKYJgkU4MTQOaHZQOmFRDwDevH0MXcsuHrEXL@QS5YEuNCfEWEepmDVbMLCsgD4rEHGQx4OyVhJJyr1Vb7ymD2mFrnDAJ3@PWspTNB50dRc735KivEsCUcq@ikdxABJqrM0oWxicUIdUAXiQxnPYbnzqCs94yHI3x8eaHwvY0rGfimBLhyUD4RcQsV9xF4wap6LGryc5xwQydjL8ebo/U/Slf/IqkwCkKowtOiHKfIKts9iq3wxR0xj4TAljiC1mQyWrkLhZ4jl5VmoBs5C/NdtF3BZEjb1ak7oc5USH8dC0nm6TrGsNciJrp82EH7iHPoWZRzjoRTKISxmX8MwQpbnLqwbvurKRALp9Dqzb5cXFsMsHRN2a7dqq9gphRzhzB8QcskHjmiZ9hGgH3KwytUTmaK6mj6aohAQG8vWqz@8aVa54thLKDxxNF3t0foiKbXhBy4uU6l5L5mPzn032FwigVrh6c4@z4fqsrT0iVhP36jdedLrq8uKBUKa1iO81IskFWnFHAhxQb2P6ubCQ1dJsOwIS@zfMKhqwJxXG16PC6/H@s@tfPfmzXu1pt/r8ecWAQZZGM3vK5ZlZW8VSj2aD58ESrKE81GZFbETeYW8s//8OQLeT7UxpNMc@fPyfnAu2Fhqxuk/q5zZVvmgLqsV@bmMUVv9Do2QypxJ4/vBalrb5CODtSOnCVVSQdI4hjsCMgSMp@YMT4jLiM3vq4kqDJfjLRE8kfliJOvWZ3Y8ShAVQ1lWZHFKI68q9Dh70F6FM5vQQSqm3kLwcbPe/yHWPIaTh8quGJZFWV1lOfd7euIj@f0td5ut9Df33gT7s9sz6yHE1nN2WrlIhkjivIvppdeTw/M@hquPWh0m4wPUjvP7c8tYroKM00vTS6eq13MPaRUVzYiGTLnaw@NKG/oBqTlGyX7446fDg980JsUR1LK4uq4k916EyFii@H1KgCFWl//TCtUmZSghjR3f3fA9Hl4SZwFDLjerXPBRFdz3NQ@q7apPwBzPZnVh7s5bL@PhLREUpQuShxzPk3irKh3zoao4UcdH8IRPgqu0jQq3KpoapIdErCLMv/8VzQrxAStykvAcheZAyC4QldEwHb9WfKuK8@3eIXFQbioZ@kT/yvnaz/UGMfc@fnd84p/WiG5O9JmgspNQhfO9wNVhiCXHBypKz@q8RDUh6kxsrOo8NB7oOWTuktU9aoscbVthK9IWIlOC8sE5LMim7GJZgTJxc9auENlMgpNaSswJuUEfiD7YCUmw6eOpOkosy@ak/ZAQFnOw9y3rlcqa0XA1N9rqHOjodjpqlLEolbX1yVk3OvXyORpo5L7ymxOJxwtPqgLN37Xpdvybm5xOdf22Zi90x/sTZGcYnexSVJehyY5ZQpWWxVIVPObFsCrXUMOFQyqTuqzi5qWXFKkPjyIxzim7B@VCuTwokWC6ZC/O0cRGEWDqTQuJbimKqtq6L7l0gwj33o4aRNeetPlybw7Ai3nrh34ky5QMQ6SeyqqgmCjFsrFqfFDboXp0XVcbh1IFisSq/gWNMJqpqmfpFhj/ZTbuY/y3anzmSZV6TxqZ6iBP8FsIJ3zJx2YnXyEFAbN/rhBCYPzXanzS9Z2701X91CMxFlUI/rMMAteUvTtWvYUZ8WKb7P6BCcGmZMWPP9WvQg@/Aj0Ve792HaeIMqbXUvbZuoWEF13SLbr9rpBitqbeF57rta4tM25PPc8L7Y5lDttBfWO9XjfFumUKJ7DtFy@kWd@aeds8d3VXn2CRY8Z2CwZqmbRtipZJdywzajfX1Q481uv2NTbcoc28NumtZ74AUg3MZAzdf84sM7dlNeu7bnAL@T6nXJheI6Gja0sn@kT@ciDZm7xelzK45rkU4M7rHtYhOYA/9JQztWbK9wZJS7lbbRn6X381ri6CLU/f0be8nvvLrm5tk@3tn@1tQtbwIdtWs2kfGi3xUg9e6prR2fhxazfYTG86a2frRVGs39Xrd3d3X2lGm3TWAuPKuPJjP5n4wWVwiRGf@J8n/tAfBlEQBAc@@@T3Jn7PT4MIV4Y/f4Ih9/sTf@ALXwTBxE8xCCd@iEEf14F81QeRz/jjvi9pSxaJHwfq4/vW2bmtGSdrmnGxc3GjqaNaFkPzD7yC7qTZb@o2/N16ZUMrwYZtO5Yv/f@lfRbs7Fhbm3anY201bbyuEat7jf9bW15OLPvUvsWg@rdrxsst65v6q9lf@0vbkCLctL124DVftiftVyc7Zn237uzi0@7Ud2a310an7jqOe@pp5@ff7h3tnZ@3A8PzNMPtunrQ1NfWNR0fOdXusQEXaxiZNdmg1OQyZyN9mRprWlv@vIdEgTm5XG0w/FNDBaQmSEL@k3d7bxvBjmM01eDw0xtDPm0@PDbxuCEfP@x/t/9xf/9PjeDgw/7e4f5374/3Px1UY5tQOBwhde97cacZ33wRDQa8@cXF2k1ws2V6Xq3W3CTo1jpGp/m1i2BtkLZRgR98bRumiM7Oz87d05@bzearV6@8enPjy93A0Jtb/wM)

### Rundown

This program prints **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. I tested Incident locally on my own system, using the official interpreter.

Note that I added a few changes to the test driver in order to make it easier to spot hidden characters; various NUL bytes had crept into the program's output in certain languages. I've decided that this probably isn't a problem, because a) a wide range of submissions have been doing it, and b) the Befunge interpreters seem to be adding extra NUL bytes even though nothing in the program implies that (unless I've missed something), so it must have been going on for ages and is probably part of how the interpreter works. (Note that the languages that still output NUL bytes – the Befunges and Minkolang – haven't had their code changed for this submission.)

The previous Rail submission exits via crash, which is disallowed, but this is easily fixable (by adding a `#` at the end of the Rail program and adjusting the Hexagony to match) and so I didn't consider it a major problem. The Rail in this solution exits correctly.

### Explanation

#### How the INTERCAL code works

INTERCAL parses the entire program. However, syntax errors are a runtime thing in INTERCAL, not compile-time, and this is often used to create comments. (If a syntax error attempts to execute, it'll crash the program with error ICL000I, contrary to what Wikipedia incorrectly claims. But if you can prevent it executing somehow – and INTERCAL has a *lot* of ways to prevent commands running – it'll quite happily not execute without causing a problem.)

As such, we can prevent garbage at the end of the file running simply by exiting the program explicitly first (something that's required anyway, because INTERCAL crashes if the end of the program is reached without an explicit exit command). Handling the start of the program is more interesting, and exploits a parser bug. You can write something like `DO %20 READ OUT #8` to output `VIII` with a 20% probability (and otherwise do nothing). As far as I can tell, C-INTERCAL parses the lone % on the second line as indicating a 0% probability for the first command to run, and thus ends up consistently not running it every time. (I'm not sure *why* it parses it like that, but looking at the compiled code shows it generating a random number and comparing it to 0.)

Here's how the INTERCAL program looked before fitting it around the rest of the polyglot:

```
DO,1<-#2
DO,1SUB#1<-#52
DO,1SUB#2<-#32
DOREADOUT,1
PLEASEGIVEUP
```

This is fairly simple: instantiate a 2-element array; set the elements to 52 and 32 (decimal) respectively (INTERCAL's string encoding is best left unmentioned; I've forgotten how it works and had to do various experiments to figure out *why* these numbers encode `35`); read it out to standard output; and exit the program. I added an additional PLEASE at the end in order to terminate the GIVE UP statement, starting a new statement for the garbage at the end of the program, whilst keeping in acceptable bounds for polite conversation. Of course, the INTERCAL doesn't look quite like that in the finished product; I'll explain why as we go.

#### Buried under a load of `S`es

The most obvious issue with the INTERCAL program is that it contains the letter `S`. This is pretty much unavoidable, as there's no way to index an array without using the letter in question. However, `S` is an output command in Underload, and there's no way to prevent it parsing the entire program. The only solution is to place the INTERCAL code inside parentheses, Underload's equivalent of a string literal, so that it doesn't run immediately.

However, we have two `^` characters at the end of the program, which execute Underload code; so those `S`es are going to get executed anyway if we don't do something about it. I could have changed it to another character, but decided it was easier to protect the code so that it becomes meaningless. `a` escapes a string in Underload (meaning that `^`, upon executing the string, will simply unescape it again rather than producing harmful side effects). We already have one `a` in the `say` used in the Perl 6 code (which in this arrangement of the code, is actually enough due to unrelated changes). However, so that people don't have to rely on that, I added another `a` at the end of the line (I wanted a character there anyway to make what would otherwise be trailing spaces visible, and because Hexagony needed padding as it is; note that the Hexagony was fairly easy to fix in this program, and doesn't really need separate discussion). So the Underload code is a little less fragile than it could have been.

#### Prelude to a lot of work and confusion

Ah, Prelude. Not normally the most difficult language, but it definitely was this time. There are two real problems: one is that adding extra parentheses on a farly long line runs the risk of disturbing the control flow of the Prelude program (as they create the equivalent of a `while` loop), and one is simply the problem of preventing them lining up vertically (which is responsible for most of the random moving around of whitespace on lines). Note that the Whitespace gave me some trouble too, but this program is equivalent to the previous one from Whitespace's point of view, so it was pretty much a case of "fix the Prelude without breaking the Whitespace".

I'm not too sure how the Prelude actually works at this point. There are several fixes intended for it, like the 0 near the bottom-left corner, but they clearly don't function in the way I intended them to. (The Julia code also ended up moving to the bottom of the line because the parentheses in its `print` statement were really hard to deal with.) Perhaps we'll just have to leave it a mystery.

### Breakdown in a Fission reactor

Although the changes above were for fairly subtle problems which are hard to fix, there's a much more obvious problem; `DOREADOUT` matches the regex `R...O`, and thus will cause Fission to produce unwanted output on the fourth cycle, which is not enough time to output the intended output of `12`. And INTERCAL only has one instruction that produces output (unless you count crashing as output). One fix to this is to try to add whitespace between `READ` and `OUT`, to give us time to intercept the output, but that makes Whitespace angry. So for a while, I thought this program was impossible; `R`, `L`, `U`, and `D` are all entry points in Fission, and all capable of potentially running problematic code, and INTERCAL keywords must be in uppercase.

However, there is a fix, and a fairly surprising one. As part of an internationalization effort, C-INTERCAL actually accepts keywords in multiple languages, with support for both English and Latin. We couldn't avoid `S` like this, but we *can* avoid `O`; `FAC` is a perfectly good substitute for `DO`, and likewise `LEGERE EX` means the same thing as `READ OUT`. (The program thus ended up in a mix of English and Latin, but that's OK; it hardly makes it any less readable.) As such, we can happily let Fission go mad in the bottom right corner, and just not let it produce any output. We can change the *actual* Fission code to end with `*` rather than `;`, which quits the entire program rather than just one thread; this code runs fairly quickly, so it exits the program before all the stray entry points have time to do any damage.

#### Knit 6, Perl 6

The next problem: The Perl 6 comments work by matching `<` and `>`. INTERCAL's assignment operator is `<-`. Luckily, that adds extra *opening* brackets, so I could just add a few closing brackets to cancel them out in an unparsed location in the program (just after the Pip code, in this case).

However, I didn't want to change the whitespace budget of the program, but moving the Julia code (for Prelude) ended up adding an extra space to the last line; I had to remove one from somewhere. The double space is a comment marker in Pip, so I could hardly change those; the only remaining option is the space in `say 27`. Perl 5 golfers would immediately think "well just do `say+27` then" (unary `+` comes in handy surprisingly often!), but unfortunately this isn't valid Perl 6 syntax.

What we *can* do, though, is to change `say` from function syntax to method syntax. Integer literals have a bunch of methods, including one to print them out, so `27.say` is a perfectly valid program of the same length.

#### Be square? Don't be there

So the next issue is that I've added an extra `.` to the program. SMBF users will know that that's clearly a problem in that language, producing stray output (NUL bytes in this case). There was *already* a `.` producing stray output last program, but that doesn't mean I shouldn't take the opportunity to fix it.

The basic idea here is to create an SMBF loop to comment out the offending instructions. This means moving the square brackets around. I took them from around the SNUSP code (because they were only there for the sake of Incident anyway, and Incident doesn't care *where* in the program they are), and placed the opening bracket at the start of the INTERCAL code, and the closing bracket just before the Trigger (thus neatly hiding both `.`s).

Unfortunately, square brackets are meaningful to Retina; it sees `[…<-#…` and says "that makes no sense, you can't create that range because `<` doesn't come before `#`". Fortunately, this is easily fixable with a strategically placed backslash.

#### The centre-of-the-program incident

This happened last answer, and it's probably going to happen repeatedly from now on; various strings happened to randomly occur three times, and shifted around the centre of the program from Incident's point of view.

The most urgent token to handle was `1#`, which appears three times if you make these changes naively: `#= >␉1#` at the start of the third line, `__DATA__=1#`, and `echo 21#`. Why is this a problem? Because the `1#` on the third line overlaps the `#v` just after it, and two overlapping tokens causes neither of them to be counted. And `#v` is the token we used to comment the code before the Incident program out! I fixed this by sneaking in an extra `1#` very near the end of the program (only three characters follow it); none of the languages that parse that part of the program do anything with it.

There were various other problematic tokens to deal with. A couple were single letters, `P` and `U`; I dealt with these via changing a couple of filler no-ops in the Incident code from `x` to `P` or `U` respectively, giving a fourth copy. The change to the Fission code leaves `*` as a token, but notably, this is split differently from normal, appearing twice before the Incident code and only once afterwards. Instead of removing it, therefore, I used it to partially balance the new `LE` token that appeared in the INTERCAL code. That's enough to drive the centre of the program back over an `0o` token. Of course, changes to the program are quite likely to disturb this. (My attempts to get Incident onto TIO failed due to libdivsufsort not being available there, so it looks like we might benefit from a new interpreter, especially in JavaScript so that it can run online. If you're interested, take a look at [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107533/62131).)

Comment: Wow, this challenge has come a surprisingly long way. Great job!

Comment: Latin?! Wow, what a great solve! I love that the code says 'please give up' now. It's like it's daring me to quit.

Answer (score 21):

## 31. [Modular SNUSP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SNUSP#Modular_SNUSP), 326 bytes

### Program

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::T):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12"; ␉
#[␉
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9)or(13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21#|/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
#8␛dggi2␛␉` |1|6$//''25  #>say␉␉ 27#T222999+/+23!@"26
```

As usual, `␛` is a literal ESC character and `␉` is a literal tab.

### Rundown

This program prints **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Why no links in the rundown? Because I've been working on something to make testing much easier, a test driver that runs the program in most of the languages listed here and prints the result. This should hopefully make adding future languages to the polyglot much easier. You can get the results of this program for 28 of the 31 languages via running the following TIO link (which is a test driver written in a mix of Bash, Perl, and A Pear Tree):

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVfLetu4FV6Hr5DNGYoTkZFJWHTsxNZlnGScfklnMmnsmS5sjw2RkISYBDkAaMufL1@33XXfF@h7dNun6IukB6AkS7Y8U9kkQPAA5z/3w68N84NPRXY5ygoNmikNqeTnTEbw5hJ2KVeb8UbkOJZMFmmVcDECPWbARVlpGPKMKSehGvpQTo@JzAQaIBlNazJnWEgwWyA/y2D6a4AqcrOomSwlw7sCwVgKqmQJH/LEHg5soplQvBDKSQvHbEzKe6zmTx5DGsFmcFlJpYVbQGmxz1BfSFqWyM9pwD5i0DxnCrhuKmBUcaME3KKYSK2k5Vw9BVCxCBjOOQWKclTSnq2Y1Ig0sufCmEmGR1LDfCRpDv6F5BqlMYp4DZ8YlXAgGQuQCyqQqYSWiGOJJTIrDAdtBImsorvd5t5P75qo8HpHREvtNOTGwV8@OBSiHngnHbx6rttx9j5@D1fekZkjCjwMjVJKnwbQuwVFjo4YXpP2gIzkjYOnOqiVDEhRaoInU6kR3t0sPI@jMltgC917llhwgpoqRVugrEN2ARkVo4qOUMJCIClNElbqqUEKgSKmXNyX0C6GU3NFaux4u/d5WthTQy7w0PSM1aqcKp8aSyRFnlORhhkXDKgcVTlDnaRcskRnl/e5I8H5PebuqSFZAnDqPgJh5nPoM2zCkkrTQcbW4GLMkzFcWHQCxvScGceS1QPhcWmRu8whHM5ZGzDt/rPYich8ycB49IjQmPbhOWhQc1R/acF6weKCFdBG1b4JTprNQwhMaM8jdi48auODcRDJfqtQuwoUHwlDQsU8/NAaKat9nyvR1BhNiqOKTCBxfHPw/icTSX9ldVpAJdU@tZB@cG3Icfs0UMyLmcYclowLCAU0pxh81/r1F4RFlEzsJFwIZjeIUF2@UZt9NTvoS53f7js29B/SWZbNNTh03eM1GNJMob1FlWX4UInE5AafBVfoGAlTKkLvLiodmayA6NwWC26WCfVYFhfAboJOcxU7a5ADlPmHArPcDxzzVjGE9wsJ1Sbeick3R45bXupxITaWvdc1b3bgFxswGDZFAVlR50zUhru4z6rvRy7OCmNmks9mJ@tRezMqF/IwZvmHO4dcje1tiXSOoaaNV7yxu1U@GNrbCgJh/OiecuyLvBBFzRzVwQUln@0QYTiuQrDs9Uvs3zC0y4iF2xtkwAUZsOFjlO/evHlvaYaDAX@MCNVgStpsXEEmq8EqLQ2oGj/IirCk54NK6ixMiTYj@8/fUtT3Q2uM6aXSNDmbT04EuzCWCYePGme61TzY22pDfqkyrIp/cEZCJcpAs/lk9Vk78JmhM3LsDGwxRKRZhrGHKsPssOQ3NTTJsipls3H1oVaHy8kVBM9NcShNx/HIjnvVoGZYiRS9pqApqUs0Z3fWq/XMJnRUiEuykGkiOfg/YM0SNtzVZD2udFXfTSH@Izvx0ly/F25TyvXN12/ae9PhEXoEsfWYn9YhIil65buMnpGBmZ4Mcbpa1FoYyUcjJmfjY2RM2SQTDoriLKw7LUWwhmKvWtKE2VC7e1zpQz9iHc6w2dr/@PP@p99zJptQP1disXFQa9POCde4BEzYWHhUNGtGG3dvQVCs/5iBzXxWCTv4hBzVuKiyFKu9SNHDfhbc1r6kkHXnsQYDrGY2cv/9L@yANc8yGDGtIOeKZlg7TV@M7cW4uPjO8rVOEb59vQ/hHjQthiG434Yv15W7Bt7rz3/65XD9uAmuN3GnQNG3sBdJFwDXwoBv5p9s9ps2S3ldDIxM7MI2S0khzrFXMn24mSssNvgY2KN9jPgca3C4r2HT9PVMY6@1iSNSYuHG9ho5WVLwJnA9BZ@ViDzv3aXWxdJFvmeDyvoFNp3xRs8ix66227czydKiA9jeXnlRf/36WtFL171pBgv9/95ES4pmxhKYUwPcMd8ERvSi0kut4QXX47qHwcYmGVNJE/s1MutHDMMheh5k@EVjPiisqykjBhjl1L1G3TWFeaWHryA0smGDzch///FPMuqYZlvj/O/1/FdidEGaD5pZe9Ac6CJIrOHTXILOZPpvpHqLauB6B3b/zIRgl@CjaXMqsbmuMLplsDb7gsPJW/S9hK1Aute8yoqEZh7pWP12bhQ5PD2CJ0fimCDcS/KURKRz5XtZ75IQkgR93xv32q2N562WJ577ngjbQfDsmbHJjad63knkRu4EiUIvCzqof9@jPU90PNr1vbQXP7c78LHVCq5ww60i0ZVHb4j37EiQNVyRDD9BFfM9FZgOZj2K2jcI7kvBhUfWclpe@S64E6ADZdh7vNUyGCLvxAC4JUf7LUSOOt8n4D2zU6tyMso71v2by3r/@rVxftreIm7X3SKD6Ldd19@BnZ2DYAfgCf5gx4/jYL/RES/c9gvXafQ3Pm7ttjeL6/6TX59rrZ/ftlq3t7ffOo3erfjQ/ey2Y/zkeuI0DvE67Z5eO5at77Nzmvlu@2gSD2M3MJ7lbweoofZGEIT@ull4Efzqt4Nu19/aDPr9rRhfN/2jK/y/Cczt0A@Og5vZkxmbjRdb/qvW9vSv903Qa9T82i@DxnHD9qVxu3FNem0Sv@hNetuHXa@12wp38dfrt7rT4btGvxWFYXRMnMarp@loxOOnT07hun295RHSbMabmEj6GGyokvhl4yCO4@3t7RZpxRvf7Lrx1v8A)

The link also produces the `␛`/`␉`-formatted code block seen above, and formats the code into a hexagon for you:

```
          # v 1 6 / " < " 6 / b
         . q @ " ( : : : T ) : :
        ( 2 2 ) S # ; n 4 " 1 4 "
       # > 3 N 6 @ 1 5 o | > ^ * t
      t t * ~ + + ~ ~ ~ % # = ~ n J
     < R " 1 2 " ; # [ # < | p r i n
    t ( ( e v a l ( " 1 \ x 2 f 2 " )
   a n d ( 9 ) o r ( 1 3 ) ) - ( 0 a n
  d 4 ) ^ ( 1 ) < < ( 6 5 ) > > 6 2 ) o
 r ' ( \ { ( \ { } ) ( \ { } [ ( ) ] ) }
\ { } ) ( \ { } \ { } ) ' # 4 6 ( 8 + 9 +
 9 + 9 + 9 + = ! ) = # p r i n t ( 1 7 )
  # ] # e c h o 2 1 # | / = 1 / 2 4 = x
   = 9 [ < $ + @ + - @ @ @ @ = > + < @
    @ @ = > + < ? # > + . - - . ] / #
     8 . d g g i 2 . | 1 | 6 $ / / '
      ' 2 5 # > s a y 2 7 # T 2 2 2
       9 9 9 + / + 2 3 ! @ " 2 6 .
        . . . . . . . . . . . . .
         . . . . . . . . . . . .
          . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Three languages are missing: V is too slow, and Reng and Modular SNUSP are not installed on TIO. Luckily, all three have online interpreters:

- You can test the program in V/Vim (intended output: 2) [here](https://tio.run/nexus/v#NVBNT8JAED23f4HLsoPpDpuy7lAWWnZrzx48KDc@UhREElMUG4Kx9K9jifjezLzMe4dJ5gyHXBvFLTfqufeZcZGwJJlgwpjXgCWCCJ9gXERcR9yHtP9gMj3YVam36JZl2a2lrOv6xgdXF/f2kWviY@b5MG06t3nlf@y3RSnE@rB8F1zPjvRKHJfFiokYd3uh@4ihuL0YES6ERmuFGWCaGmriQMx@mjrhZUwFzvH0v100gMiIkYyvdG108HdPDxHmsH552zHSUCmnFUXu6OKp7chMhlkDl0p7lTtIZS8Me3Plw6i12my21PJyVunKdJQKAhowBunX8rt5CQ1hQkRxHEslqd/OOJnz@Rc) on TIO.
- There's an online Reng interpreter (intended output: 19) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- There's an online Modular SNUSP interpreter (intended output: 31) [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html). (It's advertised as just a SNUSP interpreter, but Modular SNUSP is the dialect it actually implements, as seen by the `@` signs all over the page.)

All three produce the intended output, so all 31 programs are properly tested. (One thing that concerns me slightly is as to whether the Whitespace program is terminating correctly; however, the whitespace here is identical to the previous submission, so they're both right or both wrong. If it turns out that the program is indeed terminating incorrectly, both programs are likely to be fixable in the same way.)

### Explanation

First off, the Hexagony, which always seems to need changing. It's actually much simpler than before; I moved the Hexagony code to just after the Trigger code, meaning that it's very near the end of the program, and the Hexagony "capsule" that prints 23 and exits gets to run almost immediately. The last line generally looks like a good place to put the capsule, as it means fewer commands that might potentially disrupt the Hexagony will run.

All the other changes are to do with the addition of the Modular SNUSP code. The first thing to note is that SNUSP starts executing at the first `$` character in the program, and is a 2D langauge that exits after going off the edge of the program, and thus by placing the SNUSP program at the end of the long line (inside the Thutu code, at a point where Thutu will accept almost anything), we can ensure that SNUSP doesn't see any code from other languages, and most other languages won't care about the SNUSP. One language that *did* care was Perl 6, which is parsing angle brackets; I placed a `<` immediately before the SNUSP code to keep it happy (as the brackets were naturally almost matched anyway). The other language that cares is SMBF; `.` outputs in both SMBF and SNUSP, and we don't want to create extra output. Luckily, as seen by SMBF, this program is `<.>>[…]` followed by the SNUSP code, i.e. the current tape element is 0. So enclosing the SNUSP code in square brackets "comments it out" from SMBF's point of view.

As for the code itself, it uses a well-known trick for writing constants in Modular SNUSP in which you write a lot of "start procedure" commands in a row and effectively create a sort of base-Fibonacci number. The basic idea is that `+` encodes the number 1; `@` adds together the number represented by the code after it, and the number represented by the code after it minus its first character; and `=` is a no-op (thus `@=` will double the number to its right). In this system, I picked `@@@@=+@@@=+#` as a representation of the number 48.

There's a problem here, though; the standard method of writing constants in SNUSP leaves the control flow behind the start of the program, and with a oneliner (which I wanted to write here for obvious reasons), there's no way to change the IP to point in any direction but right. This means we're somehow going to have to get the IP to pass the entire constant definition and continue to the right, without the program exiting (which `#` would normally do). In order to resolve this, I carefully used a definition of the number for which `+` was always preceded by `=`. This means that I can write code to set the *second* cell to 48 via `@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<#`, safe in the knowledge that none of the `>` commands will be skipped by an `@` command (and thus we keep control of the tape pointer). Additionally, we know that at the final `#`, the first tape cell will still have its initial value. Therefore, we can use the first tape cell as a marker to know whether to return from the procedure definition or whether to continue to the right (we're inside a ton of procedures when doing that, but we exit the program by falling off the edge so that it doesn't matter).

The final SNUSP code, therefore, is `$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.`. The `$` marks the start of the program. `+@+-` sets the first tape element to 1 (`++-`, but once the procedure started with `@` returns, it'll start running the code from the `-` onwards, thus setting the tape element back to 0. `?#` ends the procedure only if the first tape element is nonzero; thus we eventually end up after the `#` with the second tape element set to 50 (48 from the constant definition, plus 2 from the two `>+<` encountered when going to the right afterwards). Then all we need to do is `>+.--.` to output ASCII codes 51 (`3`) and 49 (`1`), and fall off the edge of the program (`]` is a no-op in SNUSP, and  `/` reflects control flow vertically so that it runs off the program's top edge); this bit works identically to brainfuck.

Answer (score 21):

## 51. [Assembly (x64, Linux, AS)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html), 1086 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPZ (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDOiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][
#x%+>+=+~tt .
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v01k1kx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e0@O6O4/0m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)  0046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
'\';echo 50;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.\."12"__*'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo  21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///89^_^_Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

Want to learn more? Try the [polygot chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpLc9tIkj4P/kJfyiDbBEgCIEhJlkyCltyWZ90vay3ZE2GSlkCwSMLCqwFQoizTsdfd2MPc57LH@R9z3V8xf6T3yyrwoZe7@zARS4fAQlVWZla@KjPpX0v0YUdxcDUJ4pzlPMvZKPUveGqy51ds3/Wz7WZLUQRUGo9mnh9NWD7lzI@SWc7GfsAzxXNz1mVJgcWkASuxlLsjCaaM45TRFhaeB8xnXpKwYeBOTY8FvoDN4pDWc54mKcczYxHnI5Yl3PPHvifoMD7PeZT5cZSZzPfO2aUfBGzEA2xYE/fqQMZm2caUJGUqo1hh@HjJLVZXb2UOmIgvj8sTNxXHjVkizr489WXqJgmYVErsGIznfsgz5ueVjHE380mG2JLxaCQklaykGzM32jwlu/Bd5oLfWSpwZzzNcTxT4GVTnnKgdIn4JHVDpl2mfg4RkCAP2BF3U3aScq6DChTAM89NwMcNkiAWE4WcDmIKRXU6lcPXLytQmNxhukmulNLWyb9/r7jMdFj5tI0/R1XbyuHPL9h1uU9jcAFkUGqSaq7OnC8ss/p9jr@5PbQm6UIBVgVSCZgVJ7kFzG6ag731yLhomkmwQZZ1bmliw4gk1Ai6YK8i9q4uzuXN0pSDi7VI3XMcOYijCaSJo6aziKQRsZ0GFODF0SirM34BmcWR1FB8KeR7MvWhsowU4g4hHtcjyUsHEOKEC8DyCnku6WZxMBNw2JnlZH6QCbYSxldj9o6NXT@gLVgnVJLrlGezIKc9s2hEeg/9iI9MtmTDi0cEFMYXIOcCqZiAz4QbniaYAjDUEIuj0tI///q30WQCPAeeF6ejwljfsVHszUIw7ApmXRgimWscuYFgC3B1oi63g8CFG/gjNyfy0VVBQjAhqF7Gs2DEYhBML3041tS9gDOOx9zLuTTxeJaDxzoL3XMZH3xptzh46A6hWEFA0BbHNtj@d9CSx6XBGOEsH@8yIzlklcz6oD17qj171OfgTTf1atmyJm1Ym1kVU3irfM1w3h2s9UnWc@LH5EVBMp0hZmAlyhJEk5SE6bk4TkZBJUfMq7OhELSIRDB04aKXvJJyNoRfLw8mbETaAO03yG8LDGudLuFumhgfbVgYrBNGlmd3gkQQX4Kw4I0CJ2w6IuLuxAWpvDjQgTyQpChmbh7tPIKlE7YhZ7vG0Id2yA4QagplbJwR4K2mhAE2qb0NpwjdK2DxZIhea5L5Yyg5hN2mV8zj5AzwCi7jHBGZCcPIfNhRPGYNo7m9/RvKz1PrwHhvucYn66s6psPfUvMBG/NLFrjRZOZOYMhxhC2u5/EkLzwIJ8ly@MjtMCgmjSKmm9lUKe/fpi1iWxHtN2hQ9JHaKyK0S2YPQYUQtRHAy5mbToQnspGfwl@Cq9vUAXBxi7h6RiA3GDhTH2BheTHByPice7Mc7gZDvpz63hS2S9xF0mFldLxNHlOb1BFyjPGKNDFjdx83FdNaTREbD6IwSKN38SDqE6rujQmh/M2Jr2N2s/AexPGKRUSojVnTck3YXiE03ObHlEkg/C2vbuFZq/RiJU8I@Hu6mFL@ywwKgz37k4hA3Gh17W9ERj@LKrgq/MyH1OkCJ1s/efWa7oO/cJnDQO7yLtsM5jEyGmwvLmhaWCpB4d40ZkbEKgUPmiru049gy8pSTwyMjSRC1U3ISSN5iaUloo8yL7t9obLuXThBslJnPVUd1HGHBRlMKJoFAV5mkXAxjevXsDWPZ5kJh4FsTcpGwJ1a4/riJmA@TeNLxhd6u3IfuT@okO9mQ3/@/1AjHvElnzjVhhrE1O/Rwx3Af7Ei7tCDKl5FuLkQ0z@JKyaikDkLZ4GbyyzDi2eQ80oduG5cpyE1eAIZ/YjMi/3o04U4Rp62zt9Fyj@nTLWvqMlVPo2j1s2Qpq5XmjJlfGeFuOHM5Or@y1zdRCU2/ORH5zHxZoXL0WnDtLdvoEDJcXfn2M@m4nED9A5bd1fE7iwcjsXjHoCITPGWxYuFMI5iSRwS8iPXeiO@TITt@zi4GR1vkH/OoeMJN/Za1tCPrCEfPwT58vnzVwJmPBz6DwFBDFRULb/vAUtnw/ukhKRoeuf2ZDfkfDJL88AYWTl98//9jxHkfVcbU/cqQxp9vhqcRvySNGOMH1ROsZVexON@RX6cBSixfgOH51Lq7Aarwf24nrI3HNaOJCcSlRU4DQI4MkSGAHPXnOEJwWzEl9/3IxUyvHkJy92RHxqw5R2zIRSIV0osKL17CMutTEKioYojDWJ3ZMka0OdrjUrZ87k7iaMra@NKMdPh72B1edmzddGXT2f5TD6p0vst3fkJ/X3NBQvIxvbBc/uw@HoAHkzsPGS70m1SRBfjZeCeW0Mano4xvP@o8jCpP0FZufx@COwvx4nrcesyo697zeYnpGgBivXjn98eH33VfgRC5G5pIJ/3onsVebjUovy3MeGUgXj8EcMTduC5AayvJW2Pei3Ghpj8W4IN3OEVNQemf9yGiOqkVmNGvK6A1q2cJHl4k@fdv0k2e8Q@L0aNyn/r1sHV4Yc4bnO0MXzQJvzYWNdZmTSkMRWW98Qe98Jlhhe4GUwjL6TLL6AN8fiaqdIN4ZHNrEdfM9RbTC1r3YfKpfXOxPdi3N6JUDO9BHh56FK7nT2s0VATTzzWW@mtsNcX3B3RVfvlqwYbezlVKQ@YzO@IRrJAoBJswy7M@O5Wkby8EY2iVeWW1Yv@Fub8tOhnZKuWYWm9yiI3FPUsjZd5UVsWzdlUdEpQ3I4Qpt9GvshLvTiVpZ/sL4gr8R9/HxUNpAnPMxb6GVKwSUQtT9R30/jymaRbUD9IEpcaUIQDgSGQmavx3QHLLv3cm8q@EVK9ty9Pdouiv2i/4uWI4vMGF/LcWBqDBzfnoj6V3IxiLnVUEF7tWh4KJjILI3bpj/IpssFjH3W8aCosC11wkhJYlKcx6bjOXrERp4glEu@PM@SKQRyfi3yfOPnH32WrA4tABq4xXpIXvbcNigwOYov@gicT0yWSTzyNCxCNhAxDn0EiV7AwLud15k1d0YNJTWYsOxBERnYhvjs4ZsYhq1DnmBoSbX@slQ/e/PldrzFwvrDQQvZiUeot5KZ@azyxM7XOliDtBUeyvrncwPJ6tcLU8lwtjkVdStGUWxmVNDim0Vioa9lRCEWDU9gdvxQdBdE2isiPqXOIAifL8aoL1LLT6JQ1pD0hahnjOGfb1F7nEAlGsiXKqGFN1TFtKc/ZZzYlWzE8Zm838CYFElBDJnTWyeZmfm@94MOZuBUvmmaz5YjjlE@dTleMUj6KqWXX@9C/HFjZUir9/vzbRnMOscUpwB9b5DmHP7@4LpvdxufPmXvFVHVRaYsySH2qsvL10aujw@OTg5O3xxDjQi8EeFT0okVf1S367LDlWbb0zEJ@1JIXbRHRVqfNAndZbpXYXpHVCR9YujMobJRBprRGTXNrNV3f@IXgcI6ICqOlTq3otCpLzuKij7jUIpx0KotbVLwrO8xWdSodYUxeFEARVIiJZCIjTTBSuskOggxWPxpBjcOrnMu6TJamq/pULbGya65OUWeqQrCZc7efBC1f4gL1zuTmsoATmLP7WrJ9bv3zr3@Tbdh@jvF/FuMxxv8txx8sktLdvp3kcSUaEsu7V0csQ2iRBw/d@caZZNEJ@45mqM1DSPBCCITAJbPr867xaL13kCeUAGGSmZJlCno8HWjTPE@eWhYF40kcjE1RYvA59ADDNpFVW7/MqCsOZ7J2tne2bGSw3LhYIhTNlgnluxKhrj9lKlMu/MQ5G3qs0@kwFTV9wJ2dthSkVXY/tNSzFaNlwCoybvcY9mDLegfWusU2rezWbJ22MsdhFbvCBm2EZKkXeLUmBgDRaToq5KEibMSFqKhdwOc5gzWnV8v7CJcBSs@Q5CR@G1kiMoBI4tZV5Y7tgl@siKTWv3FXmptqUP9CYCIFfqreZzoMFvI/91hOhPF/yXGv3zC@DO7r669s5@Bu@1673Xyns7D94yimOucleGVa02q2LHtH3/ATtUAFbskrPgMl/AB@5XH/Y5xkB98dvvr@9dHxnfazgKzcBquwSrdT6xtmvTdYDSr32Pwqaz@Jz8HxV/qwRk4Q/qfNjqxf7KZ2Z7NrjfiFRW0hxbSWK7hftM4NjnXZM944@pIH2G8xU7ZVEF8T9JQ7edUmN8u0e0V0c@fdMy/DH@ynKDNhkvTbH3X1cEf44GT/Bx5F/Ipp8K7QhdG6MyTnqV5f/vhcX/1csHGSfyuq1ts2d1i5DmJ4Vtlqi9uovYB5nfVZP@@P@xHZWPvK@sYyrfa1Vg6cKwthQe9q5alj11rVWq0cVbVyRI7x@DFdYosy/O7UVE11DiCjHOhtRHv4qVOO2mW3o5VHTrMqduAV98M1NnzJLPO67C6s8mOYeR0zKadowrVyplPG0jBNewH@PsZ@VLbqoZtcaypT5/SrC5Ev@7Ua8WCWT4mBL1b/uAbO4TXHlrg220W4tSZhW0Slyk1j/fXXkr3DmKotmq1H@zqQtyyretF/sd@u9Nxx0/zFG1RKumpvqe1oSylZ1TN2dH509B4u09SP1d4jrfuEPanW2zu71To22fX9P@HDflFK3T9Be93WzqN9DM46Z0qpM6h1embXGHR7SulaKX1aKCWl5Mw7b2r06b3o1uTn8OBHPDvGoJcc/Xh4cHxYb3aMUvPF63rz@O3zko2X7eZyhWZouYX1N4cHL16/Palj@OdX7w7fHr147ft@ko1G2SieDro10zCYYbLuABzMv611a07tS54zGNqL7vytZXRA90el9IYADaOvm93BZ6XUK/UgoUWzETQuGva5fT7HyJ83PsZpY9qY2iPbtucN/rYxnDeGjdge4cnxb//1zustqxFiwm@M541JI2pEBBpj4M0bHgZjPCe0NAaqj/jnNxpEo3ExB7HAFp8PpzpjjcbWjrZb2yv@OY90yi4@K5V@kQltN9p87uftitS1pvELN9BUuz9vjpuqjjtU29NhlXZL1w2tQXfqlv7B7nS0nW2929V2mjqW1cpcjdOKdq1d2wudHj2toQ/0BUZ9mqqUFiXywohtbeu4Ibj@2XJsq7kFTZZr@zVjHx@nW@sUX89KIyF401JOT18cnBycnjp2ichYllIy@6ZqN9XT02qFjtOmVDUOuBkgLrf2FBWfEuCcIZ@AIu3IMo40jB@5fMb55Wx2yVef71AfffzoJlX4a9uk8NJs7u1u7@61mrv13b3drW17Z3u7bjfr9pPdJ3uNut2wd@2d3e09u767tdfa2traw@r23hOrqpRGfEyJdMIyRK54XEkqhv1Mbe0i42w9UZUSohs17DrU2ozNaVehtjTTmG5VLbJs9ayk9itV65pqRAQuvb2wqhX1TFWAvdO9Lu1sL@hAC2VE5fTWHh0UjmEvOl2MyhXCV6E5oxVvxaVyuQwnetNVW@prU3Ho/43QDpKQkBEQlbLP8bb9Jfq@XXqaVFpblb5TktWDZj/RS93mExPZc2kgJ7UtzA1KwnhY0ybRZrvfjCYTv/kNO/tsf94pW1al0txmzN4hme7ufTj9cPq@Canu7anNnV8t62tXF1ZX4XvMEdlm4X3x@yD1f3IpfY1WMRyDn2a4LlZCZiTlwB@SmG/MSclvTon/woI5hfgiEWo0QN3p1UVOzarUAe0NdHYtEnZ/zDRaxU1uy8JBlkj5LI1Yo61IIOqjtVdDUCGjYA4B0CSFa8137DbzO4QM34jyBQX6LHfUHBoGPNIEF/5Ab69gVpx0sXuDl439tZoEX0i25Hm8cCSPLddWr2AvpHrf04rd@i0A1EqAqfQbleKYv@cYSEi0FYY6@8PHuLUfF5q@PJNgYb1YzK9VsVCqeT1sK3TsatJWftA8/Zou2vaX8PFj70PSCwdtPXRy@q7VwvZCOdd8CVLNndAx7HYCZtt5r1bzB06o/6AlgvnQaQAYtAlzpl@vNB05hboyvf6pFxlfokH9ZS@q2YP6rF5973yqu06jPscfxFYP6r9AeEtRarnzqRa13Q7@6M6/IYnEyWpu@8YUbTnXAudTzx04Db0dYGOt9hKHAZ9ZL6jVBjqIB1i8u7EdPH7s1oLuvB0Yhk5QH1rPXvZyDAY1h96fam5n/uxTb4b9TzV8OyAT6GAe@27qAPjAXxsylupbsy55nBN7c7AXOk71/bPq@6rz6NGn3twIB3Up/qeNteKJ@Tkxv2kjWvX9pmEJkYj6X1O/9Z9@a1YzptZhfRByPdnYKTmsvsdKsvaGxf8B)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .008186 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1151 bytes)

This program prints **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Cubix’s cube shape viewed [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)
- Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.
- For Deadfish~, can be tested to output 48 [with this](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Assembly can be tested to output 51 [here](https://tio.run/nexus/assembly-as)

### Thanks and Congratulations

When @ais523’s 50-in-1-k answer dropped 2 weeks ago, a tear rolled down my cheek. It was too beautiful. And it was in Bash. It was too perfect.

I turned to my wife and said “I think the polyglot is done,” feeling immense pride.

She turned to look me in the eye, paused a moment, and said “Good. Now take out the trash.”

What she meant though was that she felt deep joy for me and my internet friends. Thanks and congratulations to everyone.

### Assembly Explanation

In the days that followed, my mind kept wandering back to something @ais523 said in polyglot chat shortly before posting Bash. He pointed out that some flavors of assembly use `#` based line comments and `/*` block comments. Well that was enough for me to slowly lose my mind for the next 2 weeks.

There is a kind of implicit challenge in polyglots to include legitimate languages. I’m using the term legitimate here very loosely, but I think we can all grok what I’m getting at. It’s a one thing to include Brainf***, but it’s another thing entirely to include the likes of Mathlab or R. Assembly certainly falls into the latter category, and  my mind couldn’t let it go. But I knew nothing of Assembly, so this was an uphill battle.

After banging my head against the problem for a while, looking for a way for Assembly and C/C++ to coexist, I found this is the documentation for the GNU assembler:

> To be compatible with past assemblers, lines that begin with '#' have a special interpretation. Following the '#' should be an absolute expression (see Expressions): the logical line number of the next line. Then a string (see Strings) is allowed: if present it is a new logical file name. The rest of the line, if any, should be whitespace.

This I noticed happened to be quite similar to our pre-processor directive for C/C++ in line 1 of the polyglot. After some trial and error I found that `#1 “bla” 1//*` would enter a block comment for Assembly only.

And so a polyglot was made.

With the biggest blocking problems solved, I set out to golf down this hello world example.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .data
     msg: .asciz "51"
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
    # write syscall
    mov     rax, 1
    # file descriptor, standard output
    mov     rdi, 1
    # message address
    mov     rsi, OFFSET FLAT:msg
    # length of message
    mov     rdx, 14
    # call write syscall
    syscall
    #End the Program
    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall
```

[Primary Author’s Credit](https://github.com/e12e/asm/blob/gas-syntax/hello/hello.S)

Actually I lied a minute ago, the very first version of the Assembly code I used was in AT&T syntax, which is one of two syntactic branches of Assembly. One of the main elements of AT&T syntax is that it’s register references use a `%` prefix and this is a problem for the polyglot. Cardinal uses `%` as a pointer origin, so if we littered a bunch of `%` about, it’d be like a second Fission reaction.

The other syntactic branch, which doesn’t use `%` as a register prefix, is called Intel syntax. The exploit we’re using in the polyglot to get past the first line and enter a block comment is in the GNU Assembler (GAS or AS for short). AS has the happy feature of allowing both syntactic branches. You just have to declare that you want to use Intel syntax, which is happening on Line 1 of the Assembly code.

Assembly uses registers, which are a small number of memory locations literally located on the CPU for speed of access.  This isn’t unique to Assembly other than the fact that their use is not abstracted away from the developer’s concern.

There are different kinds of registers which are used for different purposes. From Wikipedia:

•   AX multiply/divide, string load & store

•   CX count for string operations & shifts

•   DX port address for IN and OUT

•   BX index register for MOVE

•   SP points to top of stack

•   BP points to base of stack frame

•   SI points to a source in stream operations

•   DI points to a destination in stream operations

AX is used in line of the _start Function here: `mov     rax, 1`. The `r` in `rax` indicates that the memory is 64-bit. If we swapped this for an `e`, that would indicate a 32-bit memory, which is totally valid to do with a 64-bit processor. We just wouldn’t use the top half of the available memory. To indicate 16-bit memory, you just use `ax`, which is fine for us because we’re just printing integers.  So we can golf a few bytes by changing all the register references to 16-bit.

Okay, not quite all the register references could drop the `r`. `mov     rsi, OFFSET FLAT:msg`.  If you’re familiar with Assembly, but not this statement, it’s because this was semi unique to AS. At least, that what I gleaned from [this](http://madscientistlabs.blogspot.com/2013/07/gas-problems.html), which helped me gold down the statement to just  `lea rsi,m`.

After this, I experientially found that I could knock `_start:` down to just `_p` and cut `.global _start` entirely with only a warning issued. Second,  `msg:` was reduced to just a single character variable `p:`. I chose `p` for both the string variable and the starting function to offset some of the `s` Assembly added for Alphuck’s benefit.

Then, I put in `;` to delimit instructions in order to put them all on one line. This is primarily to avoid excessive trailing `#//`s on each line for Thutu’s benefit. Also, I noticed that our Assembler didn’t appear case sensitive, so I just upper or lower cased various characters to avoid Incident imbalance.

This golf'd us down to:

`.intel_syntax noprefix;.text;mov ax,1;mov di,1;lea rsi,m;mov dx,2;syscall;mov ax,60;mov di,0;syscall;m:.asciz "51"`

After all this, Japt and Underload were the only problem children in this answer. Japt had some beef with the `*` added in line 1, but it seemed to be fixed by reverting to the  `puts(p);` line from the C++ answer. I ended up throwing a `(` in this line as well and then closing it on Octive’s line. This was so Underload would stop sefaulting. A similar treatment was had on line 1 to add in the `*` there.

This was enough to meet the byte requirements of this challenge. In fact I verified this by producing [this version](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpJc9tIlj43/kJd0iDLBEgCIKmlbJGgJdtyj2qzxpJdESZpCQSSJCxsBYASJZmKuc7EHPrelzn2/@jr/Ir@IzXfywQXba6uQ0cMFQITmS/fe/mWfIv0W4k@7DAOLsdBnLOcZznzUv@cpyZ7ecl2HT/bam0oioBKY2/q@tGY5RPO/CiZ5mzkBzxTXCdnXZYUWEwasBJLueNJMGUUp4y2sPAsYD5zk4QNA2diuizwBWwWh7Se8zRJOZ4Zizj3WJZw1x/5rqDD@CznUebHUWYy3z1jF34QMI8H2LAi7taBjE2ztSlJylS8WGH4uMkdVpdvZQ6YiC@OyxMnFceNWSLOvjj1ReokCZhUSuwIjOd@yDPm55WMcSfzSYbYkvHIE5JKltKNmROtn5Kd@w5zwO80FbgznuY4ninwsglPOVA6RHycOiHTLlI/hwhIkHvskDspO04510EFCuCZ6yTg4xZJEIuJQk4HMYWiOp3K/ts3FShM7jCdJFdK6cbxv3@vOMy0WfmkjV9bVdvK/s@v2XW5T2NwAWRQapJqjs7sG5ZZ/T7H76w5tMbpXAFWBVIJmBUnuQXMTpqDvdXIOG@ZSbBGlnXuaGLNiCSUB12wg4h9qItzudM05eBiJVLnDEcO4mgMaeKo6TQiaURsuwEFuHHkZXXGzyGzOJIaii@EfI8nPlSWkUKcIcTjuCR56QBCnHABWF4hzwXdLA6mAg47s5zMDzLBVsJ4MGIf2MjxA9qCdUIluU55Ng1y2jONPNJ76EfcM9mCDTf2CCiMz0HOAVIxAZ8J1zxNMAVgqCEWR6Wlf/zlr954DDx7rhunXmGsH5gXu9MQDDuCWQeGSOYaR04g2AJcnajL7SBw7gS@5@REProsSAgmBNWLeBp4LAbB9MKHY02cczjjaMTdnEsTj6c5eKyz0DmT94Mv7RYHD50hFCsICNri2AbbfQUtuVwajBFO89EzZiT7rJJZn7QXO9qLJ30O3nRTr5Yta9yGtZlVMYW3ytcM58PeSp9kPcd@TF4UJJMp7gysRFmC2yQlYboOjpPRpZLjzquzoRC0uIlg6MJFL3gl5WwIv14cTNiItAHab5DfFhhWOl3A3TYx7q1ZGKwTRpZn9y6JIL4AYcEbXZyw6YiIO2MHpPLiQHvyQJKimLl9tLMIlk7Yhpw9M4Y@tEN2gKumUMbaGQG@0ZIwwCa1t@YUoXMJLK68oleaZP4ISg5ht@klczk5A7yCy3uOiEyFYWQ@7CgesYbR2tr6HeXnqbVnfLQc48r6qo7p8HfUvMdG/IIFTjSeOmMYchxhi@O6PMkLD8JJshw@cvcaFJNGcaeb2UQp796lLe624rZfo0G3j9RecUM7ZPYQVAhRGwG8nDnpWHgi8/wU/hJc3qUOgPM7xNVTArnFwKn6CAuLwAQj4zPuTnO4Gwz5YuK7E9gucRdJh5W3413ymFqnjivHGC1JEzPN7tOWYlrLKWLjURQGafQ@Htz6hKp7a0Iof31CHhCR94iiPq6qRZgVXrBMBZZnhzC@pyCS8l@nEC5szx9HBOJEyxC9dov5WVTBte5nPiREwZbs8vjgLd3dv3CZb0BGMu6sX7wxsg9sL4IpLSwEpnB3EjMjYpWCB00Vse8z2LKy1BUDYy3gq7oJaWkkNbG0QPRZ5lB3gx/r3ocTJCt11lPVQR3xJsig7mgaBHiZRsIdNK5fwy5cnmUmjBs@aFLmAO7UGtfntwHzSRpfMD7X25WHyP1BhbyaDv3Z/0ONuMSXfOJUa2oQU/@MHu4B/osVcY8eVHEQIcrg/r0S4SCi620aTgMnlxmBG08h56U6EBocuyE1eAwZ/Ygsif3oU/AaIada5doiPZ9RVtlX1OQyn8TRxu3rR12ttGR698EKEY3M5PLhwKuuoxIbfvKjs5h4s8LF6KRhNrduoUB5cH/nyM8m4nEL9B5b91fE7iwcjsTjAYCITPGOxYuFMI5iSRwS8iPHeie@TFyxD3Fw@ya7Rf4lh47H3Hi@YQ39yBry0WOQb16@PBAwo@HQfwwIYqACaPH9AFg6HT4kJSQwk3uRjt2S8/E0zQPDs3L65v/7Hx7kfV8bE@cyQ8p7thycRPyCNGOMHlVOsZVexONhRX6eBiiHfgeH61Ca6wTLwcO4dtg7DmtHQhKJKgicBgEcGSLDBXPfnOEJwdTji@@HkQoZ3g6YcnfkhwZsedtsCAXilZIASsUew3In6ks0VB2kQex4lqzXfL7SqJQ9nznjOLq01kKKmQ7/CVYXgZmtCrR8Ms2n8klV2e/pzk/o92suWEA2tvZeNveLr0fgwcT2Y7Yr3SbF7WK8CZwza0jDkxGGDx9VHib1xygBF9@Pgf1ylDguty4y@nrQbH5COhWgsD76@f3R4VftRyBEnpUG8vkguoPIRVCL8t/HhFMG4vFHDE/YgesEsL4NaXvUFzHWxOTfEWzgDC@pkJ/8cRsiquNajRnxqlpZtV2S5PFNrvvwJtmYEfvcGPUk/72og9Dhhzhuy1sbPmoTfmysaqJMGtKIisAH7h7n3GGGGzgZTCMvpMvPoQ3x@JqpUoRwyWZWo68Z6h2mFnXpY6XNamfiuzGidyLUTC8BXh4LanezhxUaariJx2orvRX2@po7HoXam68abOzmVFE8YjIP@cFelvGQGgFJQJ43iQNcdbQmspN3omuzLKOyetFswpyfFs2FbNm/K61WWeSEorik8SLxacsKNpuItgUqTQ/38PvIF4mnG6eyDpPFvoh5f/@bV3RzxhzleOhnyLHGEfUfUWxN4osXkm5BfS9JHOoGEQ54fiBTU@PVHssu/NydyCYOcrn3b46fFRV40QvFyyFdwGtcyHNjaQQenJyLYlFy48VcKqEgvNy1OBRsYBpG7ML38gnSvSMfRbWo8BdVJzhJCQylfkxKrLMD5nG6kkRm/XmKZDCI4zOR0BMnf/@b7DtgEcjANcYL8qIRtkaRwQOaoth3Zea5QHLF07gA0UjIsOQpJHIJE@JyXmfuxBENkdRkxqIdQGRkS@DV3hEz9lmF2rjUHWj7I6289@7PH3qNgX3DQgvpiUW5tZCb@q3xXTNT62wB0p5zZOPryw0sr1YrTC3P1OJY1DIUHbKlUUmDYxqNhboW5X0ouo3C7viFKO9FDyciR6U2HiqYLMerLlDLtp9d1pDXhChWjKOcbVGvm0MkGMn@JKPuMSiKLeUZ@8ImZCuGy5pbDbxJgQTUHQntVTa5nsBbr/lwKsLeectsbdjiOOUTu9MVo5R7MfXPep/6FwMrW0il359922jNILY4BfhTizxn/@fX12Wz2/jyJXMumarOK21R56g7KitfHx4c7h8d7x2/P4IY53ohwMOiMSyanE7R9IYtT7OFZxbyo/646FGIHjdtFrjLcqvEdkBWJ3xg4c6gsFbnmNIaNc2p1XR9rV2/P8OVCaOltqloeyoLzuKiqbfQIpx0IqtXlLRLO8yWhSgdYUReFEARVGmJbCEjTTBSusn2ggxW73lQ4/Ay57LwkrXnsgBVS6zsmMtT1JmqEGxm32/uQMsXiJDuqdxcFnACc/ZQf7TPrX/85a@yJ9rPMf7PYjzC@L/l@JNFUrrfRJM8LkVDYvlwcMgyXC3y4KEzWzuTrCph39EUxXcICZ4LgRC4ZHZ13hUerfcB8oQSIEwyU7JMQY@nA22S58mOZdFlPI6DkSlqCD6DHmDYJtJm69cptajhTNb21vZmEykqN84XCEU3ZUwJrUSo6ztMZcq5n9inQ5d1Oh2momgPuL3dloK0ys6nDfV0yWgZsIq8t3sMe7BltQNr3WKbVnZqTZ22MttmlWaFDdq4kqVe4NWaGABEp@mokIeKayMuREX9AD7LGaw5vVzEIwQD1JYhyUn8oWKByAAiiVtXlXu2C36xIrJW/1asNNfVoP5CYCLH3VEfMh0GC/mfBywnwvi/5LjXbxg3g4ea7Evb2bvfS9fudsLpLGz3KIqpkHkDXpnWslobVnNbX/MTtUAFbskrvgAl/AB@5XL/c5xke6/2D75/e3h0rxcsICt3wSqs0u3U@oZZ7w2Wg8oDNr9My4/jM3D8laaokROEf7XeHvWL3dTTbHUtj59b1PdRTGuxgviidW5xrMsG7trRFzzAfouZclMF8RVBV7lXxq1zs8irl0TXd94/8@L6g/0UdSRMkv4QR207xAgfnOz@wKOIXzIN3hU6MFpniuw71euLvwTXl737tZP8W1GW3rW5/cp1EMOzylZbRKP2HOZ12mf9vD/qR2Rj7UvrG8u02tdaObAvLVwLelcrT@xmbaNaq5WjqlaOyDGePqUgNi/D705M1VRnADLKgd7GbQ8/tctRu@x0tLJnt6piB14RH66x4SazzOuyM7fKT2HmdcyknG4TrpUznTKWhmk25@Dvc@xHZaseOsm1pjJ1Rn8CIfJlv1YjHszyCTFwY/WPauAcXnNkibDZLq5baxy2xa1UuW2sv/1Wam4zpmrz1saTXR3INyyret5/vduu9JxRy/zVHVRKutrcVNvRplKyqqfs8Ozw8CNcpqUfHao9rfsd@65ab28/q9axqVnf/RM@7Fel1P0TtNfd2H6yi8Fp51QpdQa1Ts/sGoNuTyldK6WruVJSSnZn9q5Gn97rbk1@GPsRz44x6CWHP@7vHe3XWx2j1Hr9tt46ev@y1MTLVmuxQjO0vIH1d/t7r9@@P65j@OeDD/vvD1@/9X0/yTwv8@LJ7tvtt5vWoFszDYMZJusOwMds9m335uamxmo31TzPq@ZMgiml193Ze8vogJMfldI72mQYfd3sDr4opV6pB5nNW42gcd5onjXPZhj5s8bnOG1MGpOm12w2Zw3@vjGcNYaNuOnhyfHTCDH0G6NZY9yIGhEBxRi4s4aLwQjPMS2NgOQzfvxGg7A3zmcgEzTF59OJzlijsbmtPas9L37sJzplGl@USr/IirYabT7z83ZF6l3T@LkTaGqzP2uNWqqOeKo912GhzQ1dN7QGxddN/VOz09G2t/RuV9tu6VhWKzM1TivatXbdnOv06GkNfaDPMerTVKU0L5FHRmxzS0e04PoXy25arU171inXdmvGLj52t9Ypvl6UPCF@01JOTl7vHe@dnNjNEpGxIHGzb6rNlnpyUq3QcdqUtsYBNwPc0RvPFRWfEuDsIR@DIu3IULwhJ@OHDp9yfjGdXvDl5xWKpc@fcTnJj1WFE7dNCs3BSXYZ5Ugnohhp6siftc0c0bAdxufMmdWbYuD5GCDPYmnm10M5Nau32tklheRgAbzdWEA3Vks7ppO5/hVTt5qqUvJAAgl5wjLcgPGo4laM5gt14xky143vsI5bkjp7HeqBxuakq5SaKuRRVaiPzTSmg3Wl1NfU05Lar1Sta6o5tURvz61qRT0FBlrHHgV7Ot3rEpuTbOaKR2X45vMS6@s0ca00550uRuUKYa7QnLERb8alcrkM92RddUN9ayo2/XsICZrkLSQOXCX2Jd5q3kTft0s7SWVjs9KHA2fZs2@88dhvfcNOvzS/bJctq1JpbTFml6TZNb/TS93WdyZS9tJAzjFtE5ODkjDTVhMqJMVE3qeTTycfW63W8@fP1db2b5b1taCI1WVgGHHcmdPwociwl/o/OZQYR8vogMFPUwSipdgZyT3wh0Lw63OFLtamxH@qYE4hvkiEGg1Q0bp1ka2zKjVPewOdXYtSwB8xjVaRIzRlSSKLr3yaRqzRViQQteDayyGokJkwmwBokgKB5tvNNvM7hAzfiB8FBfosdtRsGgY80gQX/kBvL2GWnHSxe42Xtf21mgSfS7bkedzQk8eWa8tXsBdSJ8HVit36HQBUYYCp9BuV4pj/zDGQ6mhLDHX2h49xZz9Cpb44k2BhtVjMr1QxV6o5vFyhY1eTtvKD5urXFMLbN@HTp@6npBcO2npo5/Rdq4XtuXKm@RKkmtuhbTTbCZht571azR/Yof6DlgjmQ7sBYNAmzJl@vdR0ZBfqyvT6VS8ybqJB/U0vqjUH9Wm9@tG@qjt2oz7DL8RWD@q/QngLUWq5fVWL2k4Hv5RN3JJEYmc1p31riracaYF91XMGdkNvB9hYq73BYcBn1gtqtYEO4gEW729sB0@fOrWgO2sHhqET1KeNF296OQaDmk3vO5rTmb246k2xf0fDtw0ygQ7mse@2DoAP/LUhY6m@FeuSxxmxNwN7oW1XP76ofqzaT55c9WZGOKhL8e80Voon5mfE/LqNaNWP64YlRCI6C5r6rb/zrVnNmFqH9UHI9WRtp@Sw@hErycob5v8H) of the polyglot. But I wanted to attempt to improve the VIP score as well if possible. And since I had a fulfilled all the requirements of the challenge, I felt ok about collaborating to golf down the code.  So I stopped over at polyglot chat to seek some golfing help.

### We must go deeper

@ais523 demonstrated a technique of passing the instructions to the assembler as machine code with this statement.

`.text;.long 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597`
Machine code is a series of numeric instructions executed directly by the CPU which can be represented in decimal, Hexadecimal or Octal. For our purposes decimal is the shortest since (hex takes a leading `0x` to represent). The `.long` statement here is making the declaration that what follows is a series of decimal machine code instructions.

Well I poked at this statement as well for a bit to see what the assembler would allow, and made a couple changes. First, I found that I can remove `.text;` all together, with only warnings issues, which was a pretty sold byte saving.  Then a while later I also found, [this statement](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC102) in the AS spec documentation

> .long is the same as .int

Cool. So, we can make that swap for a quick byte. Now our assembly, but really machine code, was cut down to this:

`.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597`.

While this is all well and good, it’s quite difficult to work with machine code directly and I wanted to at least see how to make all the translations. So ideally, we’d want to dissemble the machine code back to assembly. The easiest way of doing that is to take an object dump, which @ais523 demonstrated for me with this code snippet.

[Here’s the code snippet.](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#HclLDsIwDADRfU7hA7ihTu3G3nCX9CMBAozU9Pxp6e6Nps2lwh1q3ELZoPNTftV7@TPEW4m@17DODw8@vZb984Pueq3F57dCSqaiNiRFNWWhUQQpIWXN1iP1pDSqGKGyDcxs5xXLBw)

And here’s just the Assembly.

```
nop
mov    $0x1,%al
mov    %eax,%edi
lea    0xc(%rip),%rsi
mov    $0x2,%dx
syscall 
mov    $0x3c,%al
xor    %edi,%edi
syscall 
.byte 0x35
xor    %eax,(%rax)
```

That link also shows some 2 character hex numbers alongside each line of assembly. Those correspond to the decimal instructions. For example, if you put `2298589328` into [this](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter) decimal to hex converter, you get `8901B090` back. And if you look closely, those are the first 4 hex instructions from the object dump (in reverse order).

From what I can tell, sets of 4 hexadecimal numbers are always used to convert to decimal and the main byte saving trick being use here is to structure the assembly so that the last several hex numbers in our 4 sets are 00. These will then transform to leading zeros when we put them into the `.int` statement which are just omitted.

This is what’s happening in the `12` statement. In hex portion of the object dump this is `0c 00 00 00`.

This is as far as my understanding of Assembly has gotten in 2 weeks. What a crash course!

### Incident

Incident was a more difficult solve in the shorter assembly implementation because it weighted the polyglot tokens much heavier to the top. Here is the Incident report.

- `!` in line 2 detokenizes `!`
- The first `EA` on the INTERCAL line detokenizes itself
- The last space on the second to last line detokenizes a space-space token.
- `85` on the last line detokenizes
- The `R` in `#<R>"3"O.` detokenizes `R`
- `65` in `<>{#65 }//` tokenizes `65`
- `16` on the last line detokenizes itself
- `89` on the last line tokenizes itself

### Cardinal

I just realized I made a change to Cardinal that I forgot to document. I spent some time poking around looking for ways to save bytes, and decided to learn Cardinal. After a little time with the documentation, I saw this line.

> `=` copies the pointer's active value into its inactive value.

This was not a trick being used in the polyglot. The old solution included these instrucitons: `++~*t

`++` incriments up to 2.

`~` changes the active stack

`*` adds the stacks.

I realized that `~*` could be achieved with just the `=` instruction, so I reworked the solution to take out some useless stack swapping and add in this small byte saving.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how you can even keep polyglotting to this amazing stage. How???

Comment: This is truly a thing of pure beauty.

Comment: Unary should be next

Comment: No, that would murder the VIP score (unless the code was 3 bytes or less)

Answer (score 19):

## 1. Python 3 (8 bytes)

```
print(1)
```

This program prints **1** in Python 3.

Starting this off with Python 3 because I know it's good for polyglots and can be taken in a number of different directions (also, I wanted to ensure that the first answer was in a relatively normal language, rather than an absurd esolang that's hard to polyglot with).

Comment: Would ><> be a good choice for the 2nd language (so that we start 2d space)?

Comment: So that means the next answer can't be more than 9 bytes? That's gonna be really hard to come up with another one.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem *Each answer must be no more than 20% or 20 bytes (whichever is larger) longer*

Answer (score 19):

## 10. [Befunge](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 95 bytes

```
#v02^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<;n4
#v0#@00
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8
#|
#M`
print(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5)
#jd5ki2
```

There is a literal ESC character between `j` and `d` on the last line (grr, @ais523). It is not included in this code. To get the actual code, please go to the `Try it online` link.

This prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang, **4** in <><, **5** in Python 2, **6** in SMBF, **7** in Japt, **8** in Retina, **9** in Perl, and **10** in Befunge.

This code shares `*` with Retina and `.` with Minkolang and SMBF.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69cZmAUZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY21nkmXEBxZQcDAy5lO2M/PS7lmphyLS5lCyCDS9k3gaugKDOvRMMvPy9VITEvRcEyv0jBUN8IxDQEMk01uZSzpFNMszON/v8HAA)

## Explanation

**Actual program**

```
#v02^
    @
    .
    *
    
    
   
    t
    5
#v02^
```

The last line was written for clarity (*Befunge* playground is cyclic.)

```
#
```

Trampoline, skips `v`

```
02^
```

Push `0` and then `2` in stack and go up.

```
5t*.@
```

Push `5`, no-op, multiply two elements in stack (`2` and `5`), print, end program.

Comment: This makes SMBF print a null byte at the first `.`.

Comment: @Pietu1998 fixed!

Comment: Hey, it wasn't me who chose to use a language where many of the most important commands are nonprintable characters… (In other news, I was considering Befunge as a strong possibility for adding to this polyglot; it seems to fit in well with the other languages. I like the way you did it, although it may well need modifying to fit in more.)

Comment: @ais523 I agree that modifying this code may be difficult. To alleviate this, I put in some `0`s to indicate that those characters can be anything (except the `"<+0+0+0+<;n4` part) and parts of the Befunge code may be moved around. And a tip for the next person: most of characters are no-op in Befunge, so adding more lines is not likely going to affect the Befunge code.

Comment: Thinking about making a befunge-98 (or other similar funge) submission, because they add a fair amount of operations that are no-ops in regular '93. It might be hard to fit though, and I would need to figure out how all the other languages worked so I could work around them...

Comment: Is it Befunge-95? That'd be pretty cool; Befunge-95 with a byte count of 95...

Answer (score 19):

## 11. [Befunge 98](http://quadium.net/funge/spec98.html), 102 bytes

```
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8  ^1b0<
#|
#M`
print(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5)
#jd5ki2
```

Prints:

- 1 in [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY21nkmXMplBsrxhQ5cynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhYKCnGGSQY2QD6Xsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKWdJp5hmZxr9/w8A)
- 2 in [Vim](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzw7bjQKI3YwI19xQAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOCAgXjFiMDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=) - This takes quite a while to output for some reason...
- 3 in [Minkolang v0.15](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%23v%3B2%5E0%3B7%7C%7C%22%3C%2B0%2B0%2B0%2B%3C%3Bn4%0A%23v0%23_q%40%0A%23%3E3N%2E%0A%23%7C%5Cw*%0A%238%20%20%5E1b0%3C%0A%23%7C%0A%23M%60%0Aprint%28None%20and%209or%201%2F2and%201or%205%29%0A%23j%1Bd5ki2)
- 4 in [><>](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzw7bjQKI3YwI19xQAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOCAgXjFiMDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)
- 5 in [Python 2](https://tio.run/#T9LZS)
- 6 in [SMBF](http://smbf.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzw7bjQKI3YwI19xQAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOCAgXjFiMDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)
- 7 in [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzw7bjQKI3YwI19xQAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOCAgXjFiMDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)
- 8 in [Retina](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzw7bjQKI3YwI19xQAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOCAgXjFiMDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)
- 9 in [Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY21nkmXMplBsrxhQ5cynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhYKCnGGSQY2QD6Xsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKWdJp5hmZxr9/w8A)
- 10 in [Befunge 93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY21nkmXMplBsrxhQ5cynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhYKCnGGSQY2QD6Xsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKWdJp5hmZxr9/w8A)
- 11 in [Befunge 98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY21nkmXMplBsrxhQ5cynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhYKCnGGSQY2QD6Xsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKWdJp5hmZxr9/w8A)

To be perfectly honest, I have no clue why the Vim code takes 1 min to output. Also, no clue how Retina works.

Explanation:

```
#v          Skips the v, which would send the IP down
  ;         Unlike '93, where ; is a no-op, '98 skips to the next ;
            and doesn't execute anything in between
   2^0;     Not executed, unlike Befunge 93
       7|   Pushes 7 onto the stack, and then sends the IP up, because 7 is not 0
n0b1        n clears the stack, and #s are pushed until the stack is [0, 11, 1
    *.      multiplies the top 2 values of the stack to give 11, and prints it (yay!)
      _     Sends the IP right, because the top value of the stack is 0
       q    Ends the program (no-op for '93, which continues to @)
```

Things to note:

- The `0` next to the `b` isn't strictly necessary in the code's current state, and the stack has been cleared. It can be removed if necessary, but allows for other stack manipulation beforehand as part of a possible future program.
- The `_q@` is there as part of Retina (It doesn't work without it, don't ask me why). The addition of `q` also lets the '98 code run a `t` operation, which splits the IP (along with making the Retina program print 8 instead of 7)
- The `_` is not a simple `>` because that would mess the SMBF part up.

---

Edit: Just realized that the `_q@` should probably be `@00` (Where 0s can be ~any char) to make the program more flexible in the future. I'm too lazy (and tired) to change all the links right now though. Will get around to it eventually...

Edit 2: I Didn't expect 6 more answers this quickly. I guess it's staying as is. Great job everyone!

Comment: Heh, I wrote my 11th answer, only to realise that it had already been posted, now I changed it to the 12th answer :)

Comment: Any Idea why Vim takes so long to execute?

Comment: @MistahFiggins I guess it is because the code has to be converted to keystrokes, but other than that, I have no clue

Comment: I wrote that vim interpreter, and I have no idea why it takes so long. I haven't noticed many performance issues before, but that's because most of my V/Vim answers are less than 40 bytes. Not really sure what's causing it, but lots of people have been complaining about that on this thread.

Answer (score 19):

### 21. [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/) (161 bytes)

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@#;n4"14""
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++ %
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[

print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#46(89999+++++!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21
#8dggi2` |1|6
```

Two `<ESC>`s, between `8d` and between `` 2` `` on the last line. You can tell that my previous one was golfed in a hurry, because I woke up this morning and realised I could take a bunch more off. I had 152 bytes but that seems to only work in Perl 5.24.0, so in the interest of compatibility with TIO I've kept the original expression for now.

Prints 1 in Python 3, 2 in V, 3 in Minkolang, 4 in ><>, 5 in Python 2, 6 in SMBF, 7 in Japt, 8 in Retina, 9 in Perl, 10 in Befunge-93, 11 in Befunge-98, 12 in Fission, 13 in Ruby, 14 in Turtléd, 15 in Haystack, 16 in Pyth, 17 in Julia, 18 in Cardinal, 19 in Reng, 20 in Prelude and **[21 in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvtiQmkUX4EKoTTMDg6uRoKKQZaipHEi/DpiPNsd7gyfGlXINFPhbfsuIbcxw5gxAiY6qhKTfjS0CpxzwSQEXRMoJnvQJ4aS5QTOhLyGzjrfx1BebUMz2g8UI77xd0uKmFeotUqMUZJDrPw0W4ifFS/g/@KewwUe92dPJRJIvaZtO@nVdMRRzfMX)**.

Note that Nim on ideone.com uses version 0.11.2, which is a tad too old, since this program relies on `#[ ... ]#` multiline comments added in early 2016.

<s>Thanks to Cardinal's Windows interpreter, my workflow now consists of two laptops and a Python `http.server` in between.</s>

---

Edit — some more hints:

- The `8` at the start of the last line is to set Retina's limit to the first 8 matches, otherwise without it Retina would output `2`. Note that this means the final line regex only needs to match at least 8 times in the second last line now, as opposed to exactly 8 — during my meddling I modified Prelude to get Retina right, but it turned out that was unnecessary in the end.
- The mismatched quote at the end of the first line is so that Pyth doesn't complain about invalid syntax for the rest of the code.
- If you modify the second line you might have to change the `6@` for Minkolang, which makes the pointer jump 6 spaces to land on the `^`.
- There's a pair of `[]` now, so SMBF needs to be on a 0 cell before it hits the `[`, or alternative the interior needs to clear the cell.

There's probably more to golf (even now I see a stray space before the `%` for Cardinal), but I should really stop golfing in the wee hours of the morning.

Comment: TIO now supports Cardinal

Answer (score 18):

## 36. [Labyrinth](http://esolangs.org/wiki/labyrinth), 647 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::Q):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N36!@@15o|>␉^?.*ttt*~++~~~%
#= >␉1#v#v0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#[␉
#`<`|
print((eval(" 1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or' (\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"␉*
""""#//
=begin␉//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#␉
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/ (\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE) a
#   +/Jn~
#0␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>#>27.say# =#print(17)#$nd^_^_.]Q2229991#;abcd!fghij/+23!@"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVjLVuNGGl6jV8imWlK3JWzdTEMCxm7oDp3TSSchDc3MOZhLWSrbBVLJkWRsHy5ntjNnFrOfzSznPWY7TzEvkvmqZIMNJh2BpZJU9f9/ff9dvxnyIPtpPOnFaUEKlhckyvgVy1zydkJ2KM/X62vWIOMJzSaEDot@mtk1svOuT0XINE0tz9JoGHLRI0WfES4Gw4J0ecxyLaQFaZHBlLwrB8QgGaNROU3rphmRS0hyGRNO1GGQPE3kw4Jlg4zhnBPBWETyAQt5l4eKOGHjgomcpyLXolSTC8PBI1b3dybDHHEvLhvQTImbkoGSfSb1KKODAfhpBjmADAVPWE54UckJozmX4GBJzkSkdjq4hy0lVMwLTK44JRT7GGaKds6yApK6ii7ps4yBJJXMexlNiDXKeIHdSCB2yT6jGTnMGLPBBQCyPKQDyLHAEsxSyaGQG3EV0Nvblb2f31cAeLnCpYNCM7K1w1@@1yhxm8Q8a@DX1PWGtvfTt@TabMsxpAAxKGWQWdQmzTuSe@02w28cdLxedquBqgZUYuKlg8IDZZoVEO9h5FzV3UE8x5ZsP9LEnBGUsyLognwQ5Kim9hUOs4xBigdI6SW2HKeiBzSx1WwoJBqCbPhQQJiKKK8RdgXMUlFqKB0pfA/7HCrLpUJoB/DQUCJfWraCE7YNI5riOeObp/FQzcPKvOBxLAHGUknxQ5cckS7lsVyC95JUKXXG8mFcyDVDEUm9J1ywyCUzMcI0kpOS9ArsKIiqB7D5ZM5TlFCYDDWkaqvy1f/@8c@o1wOd3TBMs2hqrEckSsNhAoGpEpbCEKW5poLGSizMq0nu5XIwuKIxj2gh2YvJlIUSQnEdpcM4IikYZiOeM9KnV/CrbpeFBStNPB0WkLFGEnpZ@jcv7RYbT2gHilUMFG9sWxmJkwyL7jfEGeyRSu6dWm@2rDcv2gzy2K69anperwELc1fVI9xVfs9YjnYfdKhJk9klXTYiMRW9Ie1hW6nAAhqGbFBM8QQueQHEHjuFeuhMPdzN@5q585izsvSp78/xkLZYet/UX6kEIUyTBApwYuic0Kyn9EIingG9ePKYOyZcPWKun8spCwKc68@IMAtTsGo2ZuGwAPisRkZ9HvbJSEknSvWVvvKYPR7Nc4cBOt171lKYoPWqrrne/SMpxrMkHKnop3QQAySp1sIDZRPzD9QGVSA@kPEcljuLutIzHoL8/eaBxvcypmTs1yHQhYPynpBTqLiP2HNGzXNRgZfznAMiGXs53hx@@Fm68p9YmUkAUhmG5v0wRV7B8mlslS9miGks7KfEEaQylcHSVSi8gFhenoVq4MzFf912AZclYVOvZoQuypT4OBaS1tN5imWlRo51/aSG8BPn0LcYxjFuhkI5hMXsaxhGyPLchXXDV12ZSCCdXmX27eLEop@lI8Ju7UZlGTulkEPs@SNCLvnIES3TLgL0Qw5WuXosU1Rb0wcTFAJibdF69Yc39TJXHHkJhScOJss9Wp8npRb8yMVlKjXvJbPRme8G6wskUCs8XdnleV@dFqY@EevpG7U6TzpddVoyQUjTeoSXepGkIi2ZAyEuqPdJXVx46DIJFh1hgf1bBlX1mLO55nW48Dqs@9zM92/fflBzup0Of24SYJCF0ey6ZFo27CxDqUPz/pNASRZwPhxmRexEXiGv7L9/iYD3U2306SRH/ry8H5wJNpKacbrPKme6VN6o03JFXgxj1FZfoBFSmTNpfD9YTmuLfGKwduQ0oUoqSBrHcEdAhoDx1JzhCfEwYrPrcqIKw8V4SwRPZL4YyLr1mRWPEkTJUJYVWZzSyCsLPc4etFfizMa0l4qJNxd83KzzB8SaxXDyUNkV/WExLM@ynPuSnvhA/n7P3aYz/fXdt8He9PLMfAix8Zydli6SIZI472N66XXk8KyL4fKtlpvJeA@14@z63DSWqyDjdNL00inr9dxDWkVFM6AhU672cLvUhn5Eao5Rsh/89Plg/3eNSXEEtSwuz0vJfRAhMpYovkwJMMTq9AetUC1ShhLS2PHdNd/j4SVx5jDkj1CPaWci24P@Fw1MJZBPqkq/L5RQopfNBZ7xbFpM5u6sXzMe3hJBUe8g48jxLPM3ynoz76syFcV/BPf5LLjK9SiLy0qrRjrI3ios/eff0bR677EiJwnPUZ32hGwdUU7109EbxbcsU9/tHhAHNaqSoUv0l87Xfq7XiLn76bujY/@kQnRzrE8Fle2HqrbvBS43Qyw53lehfVocJqpzUXtiI1UcoltBoyITnmwJUJDk6PUKW5G2EM4S1BzOQUHWZevLCtSW69Meh8gOFJzUVGKOyQ2aRzTPTkiCdR935VZiWWsnzYcsMp@4vW9ZZ6hcAF1afa2p9oE2cLulRhmLUlmQH5@2oxMvn6GB7u@lXx9LPF55UhXoGK9Nt@Xf3OR0ouu3FXuupd4bI6XDUmVro1oTTbbZEqp0WCyUziNe9MsaD4Vf2KeyEpCl36xekyJ14YYkxj5ly6H8LpcbJRJMl@zGOTrfKAJMnUkh0R2KoizR7us03SDCvbejGtG1J98G5NocgBezfhFNTJYpGfrIV6VVQTFRimkj1S2hIETJ6bquNgqlChSJZU0Pumd0YGWj0y4w/ut03MX47@X41JMq9Z50P@VGnuA3F4P4go9Nd75ECgJm/1oihMD4b@X4uO07dyfLmrBHYsyrEPynaQeuKRt@zHoHM@LFFtn5gQnBJmTJF6PyU9LDp6OnYu9VruMUocn0Gso@G7eQ8LxN2kW72xZSzMbE@8pzvca1ZcbNied5od2yzH4zqK6tVqumWLVM4QS2/eqVNOtbM2@aZ67u6mNMcszYbsBALZM2TdEw6bZlRs36qlqB22rVvsaCO/Sm1ya99cxXQKqGJxm7goUyy8xtWQL7rhvcQr6LlAvTqyV0cG3pRB/Lzw2SvcmrVSmDa55JAe689kEVkgP4A085U2OqfK@XNJS7VRah/@034@o82PD0bX3D67i/7ujWFtna@sXeImQFB9my6nX7wGiI13rwWteM1tpPaxsvdnaC9fSmtXL6xl0timL1rlq9u7t7qRlN0loJjCvjyo/9ZOwHl8ElRnzsX4z9vt8PoiAI9n322e@M/Y6fBhHODH/@GEPud8d@zxe@CIKxn2IQjv0Qgy7OPfmqCyIX@OO@L2lLFokfB@rwfev0zNaM4xXNON8@v9HUfi2LXdEYoAXtcb1b1204vbVpQzXBmm07li@DwGv7NNjetjbW7VbL2qjbeF0hVvsa/7e2PB1b9ol9i0H5b1eM1xvWN9XN6V/zhW1IEW6aXjPw6q@b4@bm8bZZ3ak6Oziarer29PLGaFVdx3FPPO3s7Nvdw92zs2ZgeJ5muG1XD@r6yqqm45CPmh3W42IFI7MiW5uKnOaspa9TY0Vryg@DyBZ4JqerBYZ/YqioVAdJyH/8fvddLdh2jLoaHHx@a8i79YfbOm7X5O3Hve/2Pu3t/bkW7H/c2z3Y@@7D0d7n/XJsEwqvI6TqfS/uwOSrqNfj9a/OV26Cmw3T8yqV@jpBn9cyWvWvXURsgzSNEvzga9swRXR6dnrmnvxSr9c3NzcDo0E7YfSi2@vzC69aX3uxo9c3/g8)

### Rundown

This program prints 36 in Labyrinth, 35 in INTERCAL, 34 in Rail, 33 in Incident, 32 in Whirl, 31 in Modular SNUSP, 30 in Whitespace, 29 in Trigger, 28 in Brain-Flak, 27 in Perl 6, 26 in 05AB1E, 25 in Pip, 24 in Thutu, 23 in Hexagony, 22 in Underload, 21 in Nim, 20 in Prelude, 19 in Reng, 18 in Cardinal, 17 in Julia, 16 in Pyth, 15 in Haystack, 14 in Turtlèd, 13 in Ruby, 12 in Fission, 11 in Befunge-98, 10 in Befunge-93, 9 in Perl 5, 8 in Retina, 7 in Japt, 6 in SMBF, 5 in Python 2, 4 in ><>, 3 in Minkolang, 2 in V/Vim, and 1 in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively. @ais523 helped debug and fix the Incident code, which now works.

### How Labyrinth works

Labyrinth starts off shifting some of the columns in the source around a little, but after a few steps the pointer gets to where the `N` is on the 2nd line (initially, by the time the pointer gets there it's no longer an `N` there), moving right, with a 0 at the top of the stack. Then, it simply pushes and prints a 36 and terminates with `36!@`

### Things I Done Broke

I knew I wanted to add Labyrinth, as it's one of the few esolangs I know a bit about. With it's debugger, I found that by changing the 8 in the last line to a 0, Labyrinth didn't get stuck in an infinite loop and, oddly, nothing else seemed to break. From there I just dumped in the raw 36 and output command I needed, and those conveniently led to an `@` to terminate things.

Then, it was on to repairing what I broke: Minkolang, Cardinal, and Hexagony.

The `!` was making Minko skip the next character, which it needed to terminate, so I just added an extra `@`. So far, so good.

The change in length of the 2nd line made Cardinal miss it's output statement. Trying to add an extra `.` on the first line made Prelude lose its mind (no clue why, honestly), so I went a different method and just dropped it in the second line. That inadvertently spawned a 3rd Cardinal pointer, so I padded things with a `?` (not a necessary choice, just the first thing I found that fixed both Fission and Cardinal).

Hexagony was fortunately a relatively simple fix, I just threw in a string of letters so that the pointer found the code. I figured the alphabet shouldn't have appeared before and wouldn't cause problems with Incident. This is also when I realized I hadn't tested Incident. Thanks to @ai523, I found out I just needed an extra exclamation point, so the `e` in the alphabet string was changed to a `!`.

### Scores from [The versatile integer printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)

Just for kicks and going of off @Stewie Griffin's comment on the question, here's a snippet that shows how each answer would have scored if it was entered into "The Verstatile Integer Printer".

```js
// This was stolen/sloppily hacked together from the snippet here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world. Feel free to clean it up if you'd like.
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 102370; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 8478; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*)[,\(].*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function getScore(langs, bytes) {
  var l = Math.pow(langs,3);
  return bytes/l;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
 
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
        score: getScore(match[1].split(".")[0],+match[2]).toFixed(5),
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link, score: a.score};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.lang_raw.split(".")[0] - b.lang_raw.split(".")[0];
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.score)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Scores from <a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer">The Versatile Integer Printer</a></h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OK, it looks like this only slightly causes problems with Incident; the program's off-centre due to now having exactly three exclamation marks, but this can easily be fixed by changing a filler character to a fourth exclamation mark. I changed the `e` in the alphabet you added to an exclamation mark; that seems to work.

Comment: Nice! I've been secretly waiting for labyrinth, so good on you.
On a separate note, the best part of the code so far (for me) is the "PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE" message, telling you to just stop trying. ;)

Answer (score 18):

## 41. [brainf***](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), 916 bytes

```
#  4"16" 3//v\(@#/;\D"14"<;n4
#/*`3 afaaZ">;[77*,68*,@;'1,'1,q)(22)S#   ␉␉␉␉ (
#yy␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=␉x
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#␉<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][<<<]>+.---.>][
#px%>~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.R␉>]|
#[#yy#yy0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#|␉
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13   ) )-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"␉*
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<␉>//
#
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  a>>>
#>27.say# /7Jn~15o|  
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17) ###^_^_LEintnd"3"z!]/}23!@/*///Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVnJdttIsl0Lv1CbNEiLAEFMpC0PIGjJtlzHVa4qP8v2e8ckJYFAkoSFgQWAEjWe3nafXvS@N2/Z/9Hb/or@keobCU6aXF2wCCQyIyMiYw74twpd7H0anY6itGAFzwsWZOExzwz28pRte2H@uNmSJAGVpcHUD5MRK8achclkWrBhGPFc8r2CddhkjsWgAauwjHtBCSYN04zRFhYfRSxk/mTCBpE3NnyA5WlMSwXPJhnHPWcJ5wHLJ9wPh6EvSDA@K3iSh2mSGyz0j9hJGEUs4BE2rOj6DSBj03xtqqRiSEEqMVz@5AaXy7cqB0zCFyflEy8TJ03ZRBx7ceCTzJtMwKRUYXtgvAhjnrOwqOWMe3lI4sOWnCeBENJkKdiUecn6Kdlx6DEP/E4zgTvnWYHjGQIvG/OMA6VHxEeZFzPlJAsLiIBkuMPecy9jHzPOVVCB7HnuexPwcY0kiKVEoaCDGEJH7XZt95c3Neiq3GF4k0KqZK2P//OD5DHDZdUDBz9Xlh1p9@fX7LzaozG4ADLoc5IpnsrcK5abvR7Hb2YPzFF2KQGrBKlEzEwnhQnMXlaAvdVIP24ak2iNLGvf0MSa/ZRQAXTB3ibsc0Ocy59mGQcXK5F6RzhylCYjSBNHzaYJSSNhWxYU4KdJkDcYP4bM0qTUUHoi5PtxHEJlOSnEG0A8nk@SL21fiBPWD8uby3NBN0@jqYDDzrwg84NMsJUwvh2yz2zohRFtwTqhKrnOeD6NCtozTQLSexwmPDDYgg0/DQgoTo9BzgNSMQF3idecTDAFYKghFUelpX//7e/BaAQ8O76fZsHcWD@zIPWnMRj2BLMeDJHMNU28SLAFuAZRL7eDwLEXhYFXEPnkdE5CMCGonqTTKGApCGYnIRxr7B3DGYdD7he8NPF0WoDHBou9ozI0hKXd4uCxN4BiBQFBWxxbZ9uvoCWflwajx9Ni@JTpk11Wy8195cVz5cWDHgdvqqHWq6Y5cmBtRl1M4a32LcP5vLPSp0Tms8OG/IRFXjKaeiMcMU2wwfN9PinmsoWM8gLSu@kgYlKfe7uRj6Xq9k3KwurncWCNBtll6Ylz3/VIIH4ax1CGHkH/zMtGQkcsCDNIMjq9SR0AxzeIy4cEco2BQ/keFhYhCxbOZ9yfFlAEb7CTceiP2YngLilVWfrNTfKYWqcOY9SHS9LEjN3ZbEqGuZwiNu5FoZOib@NBPCBUnWsTwibWJ8oDIibvUT6AES8CMDnJKkkszw5h/EDhJeO/TiFc@Go4SgjES5bBe82@wzypweHDPISEKAyHWPn49hfy6v/lZSaCjMqItO6SKfISts/DLC0sBCZxf5wyPWG1OQ@KLKLiV7Bl5pkvBvpaKpBVA9JSSGpiaYHoa5lYb4ZF1rkNJ0jWGqwry/0GIlGUQ93JNIrwMk2EPyhcPYdd@DzPDRg33NagnALuZI2rl9cBi3GWnjB@qTq1u8gJhXzEmd8h@rJ3IQJnOkSsXuVwkfFnlK16kjw5LcZp0rpuvPJqpVmmjc9m7MERJ6d3O7S8jkps@ClMjlLSvBkvRgeWYT@@hgIVx@2dwzAfi9s10Fts3V4Ru/N4MBS3OwASMq0b8hILcZqkJXFIKEw884N4GHDQuzi47gfXyL/kUNWI689a5iBMzAEf3gf55uXLtwJmOBiE9wFBDFRYLZ53gGXTwV1SGnj5@FacZNfk/HGaFZEemAU9@b/@FEDet7Ux9k5zpNKj5eAg4SekGX14r3LmW@lF3O5W5NdphDLrd3D4HqVPL1oO7sb1nH3gsHakt0RUV@A0iuCOEBkCxm1zhidE04AvnncjFTK8Hm7L3UkY67DlLcMSCsQrpZAJ1cL3YLmRM0o0VHVkUeoFZlkHhnyl0VL2fOaN0uTUXAtIRjb4L1hdhHW2KvyK8bSYlneq9n5Pd@GEft9ywTmk9Xjnpb07f9wDDya27rPd0m0yRBf9TeQdmQMaHgwxvPuo5WGycITScvG8D4znIvDogzQ90styPjeRaVHwTDyfC@2tXu@0q5@QrSNU9Hs/f9p7/00DExSBLYvK@53o3iY@slhS/D4miCEStz9imcJQfC@CebZK46SGTF@TY3hD8pE3OKUOYvzHjYyojjSN6emq8F/1e5PJ/Zt8/@5NZUco9vkpCln@e2kJuSWMcdxmsDa812jCVEfCSnLy1CwvLW04hYBubRBJ9INoWpa1IjqWstfCXJjNa@t82b5WVqss8VDyIevSeFH9OGX5nY9F1Y4qO0C4@JSEot5Bl1AWmw02QAUjQvM//xHMm5kRL3IWhzmK9VFC7TcqynF68qKkO6e@g64YdRShgPlFZUGkv9ph@UlY@OOyhUHh8OnNx6dUIg344iMAXt5TmFhjojw2loZgAQ2IKIhLZoKUl6Y7p7vctTiTj2YsTthJGBTj3GB7IfoJSCtbVtbgJCOwpMhSMv0Ge8sCTn4h6rmvU5QsETxWVJHEyT//wXwvFwUxkIFrjBfkRRu4RpHBsG3R0qP1moLrBZIznqVzEIVkjMJlComcwvF4Oa8yf@xRQUMfWPRFJ0Rkym7o1c4e09EK0UcMaoyccKhUdz58/7lr9dF3xyaSqEmFnJCb/FB/Yudygy1AnEuO0m992cLyarXG5OpMnh@LGmbRHy5tqrQ3ptBYqGvRwsSi1xZmx09ECwPRorWmuoyaWNTNeYFXVaBWkHVjlMb6XsEe0xceDlFgVHbljL6ZgJIAZdUZu2BjMhLdZ/ZjC2@lJCLqCGN3Veys15fmaz6Yiqh83DSaLVeco3rgtjtilPEgpbaxu98L@ma@EEevN3toNWckr02TvGX359fnVaNjXVzk3qksX9bUtY9AuzM4MoyBmnHRTEv0YYhElU6Law0ejH9ctiLoT5b6zZdtBbE0JOuMcE5qkkUqyOmgjIRpsJ0ohzUFAcQ0OC1IujCrspNYthNyhSXG0tUbTJZufc2ivbkw2PkXDrTdWSZ4GKOsKh0fihH@dSL6e9glPNowDOnEJxUIFHe15j1u/vtvfy/b8V6B8Z/n4yHGfy3H@yap1LzVo5cHuSW/tbQYXguD85PfwQUDsf@/g4kE47@U427P0q/6d30quMEGEVzmyo/pEU/ybzTCekEQ4dl6SxzOd6@1xIspOJrSvkZdLbv1lU7lqi2DxgqvL92qsdaJLnLaksT6zttHW1gnRDsv8pAY6OsboF7BQ8LiOdv@kScJP2UKXCT2slPmTZH5MrWx@PLbWH6tua2R3dp5lKIQqJqOcD3nEsI/7LFe0Rv2EtKAc2p@Zxqmc65UI/fUNE1f7SjVsWtrrbqmVZO6Uk10W1U3N8ljL6u5Wz0wZEOeAUivRqoD31OqnltNnKrXVqqB26yLHXjVNPUcG65y0zivepdmdRNG0MBMxo/hfFyp5irFZcsw7Evw9zUNk6rZiL3JuSIzeUbf/oh8NdQ04sGoHhADV2ZvTwPnsKk9U8QJZ27X5ih2RCSp3bCq336rMPZItrdk1jLN456yXTGd3mvZfiS3neSRVDHrhy3mDT3vi9xxuk@e1BtbT@uNbadmN/D3q6o0m@oecLANXEyRKqenG05r68G2VDlsH7INqeJuzKRKu6@1u0ZH73e6UmWjTUFq9kGjq/u6o5XXO/zaer/bbrf7Hc3Qdd3o9AE@mT3sXF1daRvaVb0oiroBfK87s0@m3qZdqlT5IKB148NGp38hVbpgAn9WZMUzyz6yjzAKZ9bXmTW2xnZg2/Z7i3@yBjNrYKV2gDvHP2uGYWgNZ9bISqzEtmdWioE/s3wMhriPaGkIJF/xL7Qswk0kYiuyxWVZyv4B@LnYkIS0FYUfe5Ei271Zc9iUVQRT5ZkKu7BbkJjKVF2xKMA@UvftdlvZeqx2OspWUwVITemd4@9SpVtXUfvqJQbln1qrPNpSnmrP5v/cB2qFyF@4pmubzUfuzH3WbVe1bU3fxuV2tPb88aIiBGv0Teng4PXOx52DA9eumKZUMXqGbDfljTqpxhFpMY24EaUjxlrPJBkXwbkDPgqTDdpRxy/gQ@SAjTPGcvgyKrqaX9PtF3Lrqfxcbj2RpQocnjrINvXaqTHuSOTi9K1EUWGWhENRDyuHvVrdPKd6UTlTnUuzXjs8lKo1gqsJYnorfZRWqtWq1O7ILfkXo73RoXnJpf@uQEWAF2JRMFmx@hURpZo4m9Lrvtl51bDbeqUpBnufXlbo7fHqtYnXFr2@2/1@98Pu7v817Pfvdnf2dr9/@3n30/tyDH69TqcjVTrNJwZyboWZT35IruzH6QWqrcrT74LRKGx@d7hxYV9sVU2zVms@ZsytlJZgP1EZJLt/sH/wbhcTSYBjnD3om5fN1oNtCMI0vzSbzWfPnsnNrd9M81txHqvLIIgmIMun8V1RcCcLf/IoRyfLSIjBT1ME3aVeGCkmCgekmWtzpbLWp8R/xWBupUEaoGj1G6JwYHXq4rt9lZ2L8igcMoVWkcnssraiCyXQNEuY5UglELV6znIIKmRIzCUAmqQoqISu7bCwTcjwRPCcU6BrsUNzaRjxRBFchH3VWcIsOelg9xova/s1rQS/LNkqz@PHQXnscm35CvZiahZ8Zb5bvQGAehUwtZ5Vmx/zvzkGsreyxNBgf/gYN/YjT6iLMwkWVovz@ZUqLqV60YgdiY5dnzjSj4qvnlP@cq7izU1/f9KN@44auwU9NS12LqUjJSxB6oUbu7rtTMCsU3Q1Ley7sfqjMhHMx64FYNAmzLl6vtR04s7VlauNs26iXyX9xptuotn9xrRR/@KeNTzXaszwg9gaUeNXCG8hSqVwz7TE8dr4USq9JomJm2uec22KthwpkXvW9fqupToRNmraGxwGfObdSNP6KohHWLy90Yk2Nz0t6sycSNdVgtpvvXjTLTDoay69P1e89uzFWXeK/c8VPF2QiVQwj33XdQB84M@BjEv1rVgveZwRezOwF7tu/cuL@pe6@@DBWXemx/1GKf7n1krxxPyMmF@3EaX@Zd2whEhED6HID8PnD416zuQGrA9CbkzWdpYc1r9gZbLyhsv/AA)

VIP Score (Versatile Integer Printer): 0.01329

### Rundown

This program prints **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required.

The Test Driver has been updated to include the Tokenizer, finally. All the C code is stored as an argument from the Bash Script’s perspective.  I also changed the output to wrap horizontally with a trailing space after each token instead of outputting vertically. This was just my preference, to make it match the Whitespace output. But anyone else can change it if they feel like it’s too confusing.

I also made a Test Driver adjustment to handle column spacing for Turtlèd’s UFT8 char in the rundown. That misalignment was driving me nuts! The “fix” is pretty hack-ish since it just looks for an è and changes the column width for that case, but it gets the job done.

### Explanation

First off, I want to say how awesome @SnoringFrog’s  [Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) Score Rundown code snippet from the last post was. I’ve been calculating answers before posting for a while, and this has re-inspired me keep it small. I think we can beat @sp3000’s answer eventually.

So I started working on this answer by trying to golf down what I could and I was pretty successful. I even had an answer in a different language with a total byte count smaller than #40. But as I tried to golf down Minimal-2D, I had to learn BF so I could better work with its derivatives and in the process I found @Primo’s record breaking [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/68494#68494). I fell in love the elegance.

Minimal-2D, it turned out, was not efficient enough to utilize the tape initializing technique used by @Primo, but I’m of the opinion now that it would probably be too byte heavy anyways. We are only trying to print an integer after all. But @Primo did send me down the path to learning how to multiply in BF, which I brought to the Minimal-2D’s code.

Then after all this, I re-read @SnoringFrog’s comment about how to include BF and realized that not only could I do it, but I could use much of the Minimal-2D code I had golfed down in the BF answer. So I dug in to answer with BF, and here we are.

One more thing before I get into the details. There were a couple changes I made for non-golf reasons. First, I moved the bulk of the code @SnoringFrog added to just below the 2D languages in the top several rows. To me, it is a long term strategic move to prevent 2D-langs from traversing the center of the polyglot in order to prevent future bugs where possible. The byte hit was low for this move, so I went for it.

Second, during the various re-factors I learned that the Begunges and Minkolang output a trailing space after numeric outputs and that this was the cause of the null bytes we’ve been seeing in the Test Driver for these languages. I fixed these by outputting the stack’s value as an ascii code (which did not include the trailing space feature), instead of the value directly.  There was a small byte hit for this change as well, but now the Test Driver’s output is so uniform. How could I not?

**SM/BF**

Let’s quickly go over the basics. These are the only valid commands for SMBF and BF:

```
>   Move the pointer to the right
<   Move the pointer to the left
+   Increment the memory cell under the pointer
-   Decrement the memory cell under the pointer
.   Output the character signified by the cell at the pointer
,   Input a character and store it in the cell at the pointer
[   Jump past the matching ] if the cell under the pointer is 0
]   Jump back to the matching [ if the cell under the pointer is nonzero
```

Both languages have a memory tape where values are stored and changed. SMBF’s only difference is that whatever code is being executed is also stored on the memory tape to the left of the starting point. As @SnoringFrog pointed out, getting SMBF and BF to produce different results hinges on moving the memory pointer to the left of the origin. In Tio’s BF interpreter, the memory pointer is capable of moving left of the origin and will find 0’s instead of the Polyglot’s ascii codes that SMBF sees. [Here](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#@68NB1wkMPVs9Oz0HP7/BwA)’s an example that can be run in both SMBF and BF to exemplify the difference.

At the start of the polyglot, the Befunges require the `>` on the second row to run to completion and Perl6 requires that every `>` be preceded by a `<`. So SM/BF start with `<>` to leave the memory pointer at the origin, then hit a `[` which jumps some offensive characters for both languages to the `]` on the 6th row.

Next, we increment the origin memory cell for both languages and move the memory pointer to the left with `+<`. (For conversational convention, we’ll call the origin memory cell as cell 0, cells to the right of the origin 1, 2, ... And cells to the left -1,-2, …). Cell -1 contains the asci code of the last character in the polyglot in SMBF and 0 in BF, so when the next `[` is encountered, only BF jumps to the next `]` while SMBF passes into the code.

As SMBF traverses `[.>-]` it prints the 6 found at the end of the polyglot and then moves the memory pointer back to cell 0, setting its value back to zero to exit the `]`. To review, the tapes at this pint are: SMBF’s negative cells hold the polyglot, and it’s 0 and positive cells hold zero.  BF’s negative and positive cells hold zero while it’s origin cell holds 1.

Next the `>` moves SMBF to cell 1 and BF back to cell 0 allowing BF to enter it’s private code block: `[<+++++[>++++++++++<-][<<<]>+.---.>]` (I’ve removed the non-BF characters from this). Here, we move back to cell -1 and initialize our loop control variable (cell -1) to a value of 5. Then we enter the loop where we add 10 to cell 0 and decrement cell -1 five times before exiting the loop where we will be pointing at cell -1 with a value of 0.

Next we encounter `[<<<]` while pointing at a zero, so BF doesn’t pass through this. The purpose here is to balance a number of `>`’s with preceding `<`’s so Perl6 doesn’t error out.

At this point cell 0 is valued at 51. The ascii value of 4 is 52, so we move the pointer to cell 0 add 1, then print the value. And finally, we decrement cell 0 back to the ascii character 1 and print again before setting the memory pointer to cell 1 (value 0) to exit past the `]`.

SMBF and BF both hit the last `[` on line 8 next while both are resting on a 0 value. So both jump past the remaining Minimal-2D code until the `]` is encountered on line 11. But this is short lived because line 12 starts with another `[` which takes both languages to almost the end of the polyglot where no further instructions are encountered.

### Refactors

**Minimal-2D**

Minimal-2D’s re-write was mostly to save some bytes in a fashion similar to BF’s multiplication trick. Minimal-2D however doesn’t have the `[` and `]` characters for loop control. Instead it has these commands:

```
/   Skips next instruction if the data pointer is set to 0.
U   Tells the program to switch to the up direction of processing instructions.
D   Tells the program to switch to the down direction of processing instructions.
L   Tells the program to switch to the left direction of processing instructions.
R   Tells the program to switch to the right direction of processing instructions.
```

These can be used to produce the same logic structure, albeit in a 2D manor, as that of BF. For example, BF’s `++++++[>++++++<-]>.` is equivalent to [this](https://tio.run/nexus/minimal-2d#@68NBvouCmCg7xNkp8cFYSsEQeVCQ7n@/wcA) in Minimal-2D.

[Here](https://tio.run/nexus/minimal-2d#@6@MCVy4gESQNghEu9hpQ4APSNCOy8VOOVRf1wYkoMkVpK2nCwR6Qf//AwA) is a simplified version of Minimal-2D’s code in the polyglot, with all the extraneous code removed and all the place holding characters replaced with `#`.

```
###################D
###R+++++[D>+++++++L
###>
D>#U/-<+++L)
R+.----.R
```

The `D` in line 1 sends the instruction pointer down to the `L` in line 8 of the polyglot which sends the pointer to the left. Here we set the loop control variable (cell 0) to 7, move the memory pointer to cell 1 and enter a loop. In loop, we add 3 to cell 1, decrement cell 0 then check if cell 0’s value is zero yet. If not, we add another 8 to cell 1 then decrement and check again. The result of this loop is cell 1’s value is set to 51 at the end of the loop (6*8+3).

We exit the loop by hopping the `U`, moving the memory pointer to cell 1 and going down then to the right on line 11 of the polyglot. And finally, we increment up to the ascii value for 4 then decrement down to the ascii value for 0 before running off to the right to end the program.

**Retina**

Retina had a lot of requirements that were difficult to work with for all the BF derivatives. It doesn’t like consecutive `+`’s or mismatched `()` or `[]`. But these are really just requirements for every other line, so a lot of the work for BF, SMBF and Minimal-2D revolved around putting the bulk of the code on even numbered lines.

The one byte committed solely to Retina though is the `|` at the end of line 11. To quote @ais523 “most regexes ending with | will match anything”. Without this, Retina returns 0. Why this fixes it, I don’t know. I haven’t had to dig into Retina too much, probably because I’ve been avoiding the long line. But like Prelude, I’ve found I don’t need to understand it as much as I need to understand how to debug it, which in this case mostly consisted of deleting lines (in multiples of 2) until I’ve found the line that’s causing it to break. I guessed at this fix based on @ais523’s comment, and was rewarded. I’m just too cool for school I guess.

**Cardinal**

I happened to like @SnoringFrog’s placement of Minimal-2D relative to Cardinal’s code. It’s a good location considering Cardinal doesn’t upset Retina, and it seemed to allow some interweaving with Minimal-2D. So when I set out to transplant Minimal-2D up to 2D land, I brought Cardinal along for the ride. There were a couple cosmetic changes to Cardinal though. First, I threw a `>` near the beginning of its statement `#p x%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x` for Minimal-2D to change memory pointers within its loop/ Second, I shifted everything one character to the right to give Minimal-2D room to exit it’s loop gracefully. The `p` in this sting is for this character padding.

**Befunge/98**

The Befunges are actually where I started out trying to golf down the polyglot, since the C++ refactor changed all the other 2D lang code, except this one. In trying to learn WTF was going on in this code, I found this in the Begunge documentation:

> The `.` command will pop a value off the stack and output it as a decimal integer, **followed by a space**, somewhat like Forth. `,` will pop a value, interpret it as the ASCII value of a character, and output that character (**not followed by a space.**)

Holy moley! We can clean up the null bytes on the output. After this, it was all just a matter of figuring out how to input the larger asci values, and segregating the code. Befunge-98 had a jump code `;` telling it to skip over the `[77*,68*,@` in `;[77*,68*,@;'1,'1,q`, which gave us the segregation.

Befunge-98 also had a command (`'`) to take the ascii code of the next character. So, `'1,` takes the code asci code for the character `1`, puts it on the stack and then prints the ascii character for the top value on the stack with `,`. Just gotta do this twice to print 11 and drop a `q` to quit out gracefully.

Befunge proper is a little less convenient, but only just. Here we have to perform a calculation to put the desired code on the stack. Fortunately, our codes were easily multiplied with 7*7 and 6*8 before the same output command`,`. Then we quit out of Befunge with `@` before its older brother’s code contaminated the output.

**Minkolang**

After finding a fix for the Befunge’s trailing spaces I got pretty hyped up on the idea of finding a Minkolang fix too and Minkolang’s documentation said that output command that had been used up until this point worked in the same way as the Befunge Interpreter. `O` happened to be documented as another output command, that wasn’t described as sharing this Begunge-ness, so I just took a shot in the dark and tried outputting the string `"3"`. Flawless Victory.

**><>**

One of the first things I looked at when moving the Minimal-2D code was verifying that I could move ><> along with it. If I was going to deal with 2D polyglot transversalism, I was going to deal with all transgressions. I basically luck sacked my way into the solution of putting `;n4`  at the end of line 1 and moving the `\D` further back in line 1. BTW, I didn’t know that ><> could be directed down before answer 40 since it’s been so well contained. I’d like to think this could be used later to diverge ><> from another similar language.

**Perl6**

I’ve talked about some of Perl6’s `<>` balancing issues elsewhere in this answer, so I’m not going to go over it again. But I do want to point out that I moved `#>27.say#` to the second to last line. This doesn’t have a functional purpose in this answer. I actually made this move to satisfy a different answer that I ended up not using this round. I decided to just leave it since I plan to post that answer at my next opportunity and I didn’t want to bother undoing and re-doing it.

### Bug Fixes

**05as1e**

05as1e definitely didn’t like the new Begunge code as much as the old version. I’d suppose it’s the `,`s since that’s the only revolutionary character. In any event, I had to move the `"` further back in line two to hide the offensive commands, and I knew that the `"` had to go prior to the Befunge code path since `"` was a yes-op in both languages. (I can just make up terms like yes-op right?)
Line 2’s 2-dimentionality is pretty rigid, but I was able to displace the `<` prior to Begunge’s code path with the `"`.  The `<` however was a requirement of Perl6. (It has to have a `<` preceding all `>`s.) I was able to drop the `<` in line one at a location divined by instinct and foreknowledge resolving 05ab1e and Perl6’s disagreement.

**Whirl**

The Befunge changes on line 2 added an extra `1` to the polyglot prior to the Incident/Whirl line. This extra `1` caused Whirl to start off pointing to the wrong instructions on the wheel. The very first `1` in the C/C++’s preprocessor directive was only a line number reference in the code, and this could just as easily be any other line number, so I arbitrarily changed this to `4` to satisfy Whirl.

**Incident**

The detokenizing string at the end of the polyglot is well known at this point, so I won’t go into it. I removed from the string what I could and added the new tokens that were required. There are 2 detokenizing characters that are not in this string though that I should point out. First, the second `R` in  `#R+.----.R    >]|` is needed here because it’s a Fusion starting point, and it was safer on this line because there was already a Fusion starting point heading in the same direction. Second, the `x` in `#=    x` is to remove a token involved in a `␉␊#` pattern, which has become more common.

**Others**

Hexagony, Whitespace, and Prelude all had the usual minor adjustments, but nothing special worth talking about.

### Final Thoughts

That’s all I’ve got for this answer. For those looking for a starting point on the next answer, I’d suggest evil. It seems workable, although I haven’t looked at it too closely, but I suspect it would not be too hard to integrate. I know it has a jump command that should help skip past the bulk of the polyglot. Good luck.

Comment: Fails in Incident (it prints `3333` then waits for input), but is likely easily fixable. The problem is that you've placed a token (`-]`) *after* the `^-` token that was previously used to jump to the end of the program. The other two uses of `-]` are consecutive, so that forms a …xx…x… pattern, which is a backwards jump. Moving that last `-]` a little earlier (or the `^_`s a little later, or both), though, is likely to be fairly easy.

Comment: @ais523 Thanks. This is what I get for golfing while writing. Always remember to check the Incident kids. Fortunately I was able to fix this one with addition by subtraction, so overall win I think.

Comment: If you run the V with `-v` (for verbose) you can replace a literal escape charater with `<esc>`, which might make working with the code in the future a bit easier. (I think)

Comment: Wow! Thanks @ais523 for the bounty. What a great way to start Monday morning!

Comment: Befunge-98 is older than Befunge-93?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Looks like they were made in 93 and 98. http://catseye.tc/node/Befunge-93.html http://catseye.tc/node/Funge-98

Comment: So Befunge-98 is older than Befiunge-93?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline my belief is 93 is older.

Answer (score 18):

## 183. [Intel 8080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080) boot image (ZEMU), 9870 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_      7 )(22)S    / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@         xxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  # {((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or'wWW s'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1  
#  
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180
#  \\
""""  
#  
#  \
=begin  
#p :1*23!/5x%6E0 !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
;set print'-';print 89;exit#ss
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\| R"12"R _* ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/| @  %"18" ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +    <>
x    x xx     xx                +++   +   e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"60"e.0,1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=los*81''cagem x=4721en nd ogola=1ay $0C0 00 3cod/|puts_e
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]   )[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//      $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/pppppppx     eeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9SZFVLJV0S/dWldSSqurepliqZDJJZonM5M0kJbJUuuhZG73zWNi7Pb2D3h7v3O7ZNTyAF/BgbQO7mAEMeL8uBvsb7nwyBob7H7TPORH54kNS3Z7xmhKZkREnTpw4EXHixIlX0/C7v/1tCj/syO1NOj13yIaWP2Qtz760PI09mbDHhu2vF1clCaFqXmfUt5yhX5JSTGfMdky7Be9s6F5Yjv3B8sC/yNjAczue0WfDrjFklm8aA8tn7mg4GA2Z254fbZWxvb773s5hzL7tdABsaHkDzxpS@Bpjr5ye0W@2jKmQ9akEBx6E@@yp1fvY/zhkptvvG07LB8gNxl64nm8hvGn5vovRNxkb71nmFNItADU8231ee/n5VNA2Y58DicagZ42Z0fSHnmEObddBnhTYyctXJ0dTMXSdvT7d35/2LbIvc67D9kfmxXTQKnvl@UbPmMa/xmqjoXswnPZfZ7WO5RisqG1rxenADfbEM2aibDLPMlptu2dpUCAsx7pWb2B5DH1Y2/XYAZDU2ypsFc5rUUzNxLhbUSCLBfJacuS5rZGJJTjsWpAxLHVE6ksmUFFlA1HXNHSwFJHBwQD1idu34szwmWNZLeYPLNNu2yanzhoPLceHBH2N2cC8K7vXYy2rBxEi7GaW@S4b@TGvZs/oaqYmYe4wFda/6DGbmYMB40GsZwNJ@4UtZmFdZB8gvNf12XjQZ77dh@Ch6bbblsU@WIMuk1quxOBjDqYyFb4tWwDjWAFjrAHUKWSMi1UQuBTw58ozBsB8X3BgaPehxdjDtM8sw7exTUIU33JaxNNB2FpdZjhxdrFLG@oMZHzkEW7f8qjUCC@UsGcBSiNsL8qVZw@Bl8iLGjuyDI@depalJltuIklIzMUUhpgRjYp0Zye9d7ifhqLlMTRjAEXprZ7@6AvJYFqFLZ@X4VuR5bK09/Ipu14@QzdvqFD8A08xVFb5lvn5szMLvmO9me94NxJglYArPZZ3B8O8kRsAgbkhEJg30Imu3GVRG/RiCbOdqbKIVTgO1YLSgPrLXmcpZ@bI81AYRUw1LiDTPdfpAD8hs97IQX44bKMARWC6IEuyzLoErkHjpTJyr4jDp10bCs3HIom1NS5SiaEgVKESC44G6fpub0RwENMfYk0GrkBUxHjQZq9Z27B7GAXCERWn2rP8UW@IcUZOC0seRKbV0lhAhum2EKjvXkJyBiAlD6j4/VirJKIAGArCpaxi0Pf/7E9bnQ7gqZmm67VEdX3NWq5Jwt8gYkGiMqywrmP0iCyAy2LqPDokcGn07JYxxOSdiUiCiKBUr9xRr8VcSNC7sqGNdo1LaNfQtMyhxSs57y@yrG9ccFli85oLGe8bTShYSoDSpmzn2ONdKCXTklJUZ3L90bC9xXKDPZb282@VRyXl0dKZBcSpmrqynM93ylDhtBXygrf0bTXndS0hPP2h4bt2SxpMhl3XKbKcyWSz4g4sR0kncKSzaa@ZVjWUcYpatium1radlpLegbpYhYTTatmsmHW71ChPRY8nCWiuEA02V0sxVVkCkUON4jLfN2xHG0zY65xwxcJc/xxZjsFazBsZM@13yT1S1F9ivXSxgoAc0vyeZQ2UgqarKCYQbm6@MWBeTqdwiAyX7EYmnUpn4lknDJDTREaxsZ7aLoqt3qCLXSUwxfEH0A94WHdNA2qPj93BEJSWLGtSvaY@BCQLycQrK@1ZrAmCNKhH1CR5k8P4ORSUAkPUhJIt2WrFGjIIAWjLQ39GGvfcK0iQaMJOBkSHg4kaHSgaiMwzUuMZ4SmRTzJLFw4IFMTWtNhWrmlDI8DmBjJd1PlY3gB8tchhABtvJDHZ0zcmgMXknWrUYJjdhrbUB/HgTZhpocwB4WPxDgUTGVH780FNQ4WtkCuuryfb2EwTG3r5Wu7HIKQ/5G9tSZj5pMoAPU/bumI9w@mMjA5qig5EMUzTGgyFoIKc@EMQRdP9DXnmROep@V1p@fF02tSJBIpFlAYKeV56ois0ULoIXTHXA2HKDKHtspbtgVjqTaZTB4DLqcTldwiSIOCdvICEQAOASmaNLXM0BKkGFfiqa5tdqLNIncPlIu@EppMHr3jqINlz7TBpJEavPixKWj70QjIWoshhic7igc4VUVUTHlT4cY/bMRt@fw5iNyQROoKYr5Y3NKh7d@Dsu447BykwMkSLIMkQXg6giZ2gOgkdV6B2UWMNdcywiKDMQGpAy4f61x0OB34J@gl72B01Nagp@VNvcjA8dLCy5IfexB663N3suU0Qyz60z3yQQt4cNe3xVIbILyzD9750CQpY22cV6Lm/GUGtU9JtHwQm@e8icCxIJsFNKPivDIAEpAGjlLZPongfhMrJxDEVWaOmpEGjk7NMxoYrq@DAWCFfdt0@SiH2hhQD1PRg5GA7bZBWQuaTyDfmdnWh7Ce9Lp3W3ru2o1ynl5aW0qV0FST70tIjcO2g6xG6MuB6RK4cuRBOQxfFyJILQ@sUA/0a6Zt6gHmsNrDYxtgrfbAHilEvlVYbWaOui2cRnyqIOpBsAJ3DB@BJq5UKOlVVrl5BRrVmO5n7XZTOJ6ZnDwQTvjAuDf4uuLBKbLD7A9dDBbaMneztPOlXPOgFQWk1u4qXPqsXzhpn12etzNlNOoux1bJRaUKmID2lr3U8dwTdpVpfK@X0hqrWV6GTbFbShfSKomzlepCQoaqfbakZg3NbSVsgtZWzszQwVfCnbnY9wjfOFlU1ZBXQgR0z6IRKWrvegvSbakPNpCGums7CEKOSTgNnTGSCT5nGmplg0OHxl5wxu5mMRNXQ9S7wOyP2wU@D4RWPvg/1d/fkeWKs278A6cpMv4eqSM7j2gi85le4Z4seocZVYgeksTrQ3UIOoLdthSMjx3Vyzoj0Z1Ju3XhCNBhECPLDvgflqp2AQcRtewwDBGj3k0ARwv4bdaFdGG66MFh@Q6qJzKDhMGzu2lxt6Ih3K5rpR3UA9B5wDnqGCQ07ie5MZmeAEOp5Pj8/RC3PIJ5WlWhUc1ceoWMxDQf517JJax/ZfhfZC5oVDiW8NnAVVXbQDSzi2gEzoc/vAKetsT3kOjzUoxOM8szwFRW1xhrXulDZQ40BiQosANSduyaMdyzQHDCUDx7ZnnNpe66DTNb2ADVU@DKWwRTyeeyFalSrHRSfLubvPOTAsRlvPcbbONZp5pq@yfKO23M7LlsBAKyamsYr9oFjAgmg8w1heMl8@wMxqNZxYeCTrIMWdvc@6oj6xmqofRsImSd47T3IGjY/0xHAgjyfHPx4D3oIfb1QAPqDtwJ9wkzGsEznET1NFgEIq18P6w2W5I@tQXfiJaqT74pRJNQn1@INk4/rDehQgSrRwj9Q1Hgj5z7QzoOgVuCal/c90pDQlBEfZSRyD8ogtFORHd5sIIepKW/0DViRQDpT4FH57oPsPO2OLMkyuy6Tz0DDKFZZvmVd5lHgyCDouqAq5yApyyNlLIwmrJDS0B2BVteyenbfHh6QsavnoOoSdctB6C40sAjBkW0NJTHeiMQrGqQiWet0OPzeGDskX7LoyV4ePt07P6qdPqvI@ZHv5Xt2E2pwyzrvg@LZs3yZTX9S7NgCZCL@h4vesesOK7y4Lnrszk8K4wTRnz89f37w5Lh2/DUngtD4dn/UM5CU0vIUAEY/oeCgVcWsgG3P7YcauS8KYnkVWW8lzMY4PBWhaxg6EkbjmP8G@vfREKyZUsc0Wc7lr6GnANxEQDQOUx/WyWQQkozFoaeA3CKUaDDWvGbguY2eoak4YUSN0M0LXxxJYL7WCzeI3HdG/iCWs2tdJ//LYbuNvXboXSTvixxW9V7kvUre3NScNPIKtswEzQUO8a0RPm6inotvJmgucIhvneND0/Z8dFMh80BDZBuEDE3hc3FNBcwBDDFtEqa4@TwK26KwRbZzkdbc4IWReHM4BQH83IVu87nt0zRKvH1IoXp3JsmBjppQxuQopBjZiljucr6RS44jopYLjevCxaFR5DovaPo6YglR9C96szHboGHQTwJ0hqjZEC4x@s02/cwBKAn7CQhHnA5ArnyBNmA08big71lXBEYjQUIG3LIdI39MDxwTzqMnObpNENO02iNQhfKgqqP7DrDc9hZBtptNexEo8AVJD55zwLxRcx7bYGTanTGAsATjhyNv2LNa4vmfftKCApgtnq4xIfUvdJwD36hutBeWloiKL/Qzv2QJ5v2oZxvEBnLdhdI00OZs9ELHfNTYj7Fcrmt4fdSyROFC5cQfEH231DNOuWf1Ri0reM5PhFicNLPw2I7dpxzBE4cJNChaEH3KSMTjk6Ldc40WYeHqsG1Fpc3LxRpzxTCmb0Hvcg86A1sOiyZPht3RcMR/cb7krnK1B/idz5VSspIV1o2mbuVd32ja1i31wDMuRi03N7joUKaRtI1FtZ03IjQ95No944I7z9E5nwE8i57d6Vhe8FwEdtUFDY9U0/wVPW6pKkH/ykhjMm7D6fX47yKQYNI7dCzmk92jn0@pkFRFTGg1yFqcEs3F2GRPMbZnNCeoonc/vWZhgqS4gOCpmJlMYRW7s9ACHk2@DgaL42MfSPG3t@fH5pOxnCXzFNc8n4TNcfME5VlMy97R6qHnsvtGL1dsxZwLhXhg@opcc0BpvJYze4YPlWkoisO6hOKjn9sqOHZGJlaryHVL9Y7ICSZCFtnUozgD23R7tj/gLU68LJKm09bICA3OitNPFBXfZvnbIpXI7@ZC13yB4JpDtGsvqG/3EHDcpIxG@1gF0txFvDPdK/wuVDG67qXFf@d3eh/mUnUPUZXrUc2wzTnRW@Zd1RVnRulnPhcv5lI1NHtz/Uvshet6XcvxWVErBEY0nJYyej1u4z49OFxcp3275/owQMPf23gBAzHf57/za3Ocbbbh5MjSGHfPjyaIGjBNWFYWFKbR67i9ja1O3oCfhSU@8trYA4jnfSVfKLl0/W7JFShIrqOL50KRf5H3Lu6qDGSO9HDaIua8pb@dJ76EuXtxBmEYgXOR8zO3X9iimFqej5YXFYBndq@MSfD8Ab3KIu4GvcpgQuo16H8YYXsLHEOPq9w/JLW121Nr3U8mzaDdvCsTscK96Fkgoel3pkhZsaB/Ygy9ULi/hGr3RtbImisxDpvvLVycdousuD9RBZGNZWFXygPz0KoUQn0Qg8d7UY39N77dKmCMng2N/E4tZ668G4BOPsDx9hE4jtAxG7HjjAaJwo3x7njkHN/Oue4gaNluK0EkhnyqRNq6W5dKqO2@Rd9FKv5e34UhstsHncG5R/kLpGSK478JxOQTYX5vo43TuxVviYXzm6DXgv4BpWpf@Dk0lN5P8BQXje0JeHsbRm@ONZzg7yJuzxOkTdftfUrpgDxt2aiWgbKJKw3vKqUZXUdMdbPIiuGjRaTZXmS/4H2NGGgC93BQvbCgjyBLQ@oc7lPKM7bWW3qtmOX1rvEm9NhkJPI9M3AvovcYG7eubWmbtxLM1VG3afUM/hhvrN2Gb1tbvY9KNAj0XLLUo3Wf2/OjCZHUlAgaTIBZdgvGKl2rb9HrLUq@0Xo/8oPHQqCxi985wVqerNML4g1saPMO/ibmDmJa0dB1YHQ1NLyOhcOTHk5qCd9FcjYwes9l7kHf6Fj7d1auyEqB66D4oC5yzrdXlPjSBBOi3SFJ@MjPdS6siR885@vHExPKc9S/Fdu8dm6iMfTOhq3l59r671D7nK7bdbpW16PGEb4tah5QI4d8ZfptmQD6u4Z/gQu/SCZFw7quH@duz@317sNdlIlcQrrufDvtHi7ZbkHUT8I7MZoQIB53mvSg6yYmUR@@qO10rRH0UL47dAdWjt4WgfbQ@MN/55ueDw7TPntjW16Lz1qjJdAY2s2exa5sIOG9H58qnW9YavZcA9cW3qLEA2eC531MVabr3WkH6RjucDCgx/mgN/Lph0y@ufZ8W2aJ7ROl96kM9pAvGOBV1uq4TbNr30VS0zKGjn2RD2w6/HV@NU8KY8q5zXJP0Vvr2cArb6JhJajEw0/wcTC/4dvPxcaSWxWS3ZHnTe4WDsmp4ND8yicN0LHIACNm7eYEU9ePq2KC1R@3zFyISb6FNYqUaVScc1YBtBN9oTkosQBIsKC3ujq8g0uma17cqU8sNGSK@WEy6dmxOW7wn7Zi3E7GMyHfYHSoPBt1fPXuitttgV6FP3MrSa3DKwhOLPk99ypmeIambzjiMTdu8fndqdPsyPqtEyUlpj8/rx0e3I3M7NkDn/@yXLs4V1WYndudhZrMH/uKompZbf57l37Xdz1cBw2KRM70LN9EOzjKYC4bueBx3A7I4lyPRcAB7FzyZ6eS52koyX4u99VLq2PguqjnNi6R6vmzXR9gnp5Vvg/iH40M3/7RyB1ac3FOzy7fB@ULo2ObzxIlECAMuCsW0fBHQlii12xBXHVtn5ajBo5FegRUtNvF4bTBPdwadbtxJKYjibWBLHfAgjWEoQNN/hhuzE0rrr67g8m9uiSypYrn3Po0f05@BpJPxh/TnqBw9bifFYuewM/2xNYVXwv2h6VogRitJQ/WFrMUrnAfobAbup7GCE5RjExGVSUeCe3GHQfAAijaoYOr9/nmH5/1bH9IsHab1ets@XpcKpT0G1ZhcklmjQbHih9aS743HtD2mmMevb5sNCrL6VwuvZw@c0qskA7BrR4waS64kYBt2/Tg9EYsYI7BlwGiO8hxme9O8Lu08wcUhBYoGq9gfEqdjevxNfZ8A8cpTlj/x79oiQ1RMBrxWd8GcQUMwd2Abt/qulePeLoi9dpgYOCGKsQBtbvHl/fndmvMv0KNhO@Dcq/Yq/3TLbG7Qmw9hJcj7DpjVPDCxaExro0c8sLj1ITr3ETCYawgU6bbG/Ud0AFbw66vsROblj2OvGj9ErgQzBl6qAi3suyAtSycFqTVrDT267nuBS1LR0r@41/wPSW0plWsNQySp71ksRRx6apOGzlM0x0B1QGSD5bnChAFmQw1fISWFWgtFvdXcaUnbXaBGpkLtnpQMny/x27thOX2WBp3VeIK8rLdVpZrx5@/rhcalW9ZP2/9p5/k1WvBOPmz3PaGL2dZAFK@wYoVD16H4Cg0zeTlscwTDBf82kLhuOLlASwyeCXDNb9BHXPdgWg1tF2PdqeFtVHsPFbQTeUc7Pno004/qrDWFe35oIV2DrZ83ELn@NDA4FUl1LzVVZaVER/8506GbB0SxH0zBrj43kBaAov7FzDK8ph9ZF2sZDkTl2XCG2dkD7fM9CtPgnUiq/HVPPmnVnNEU9iXRa24WqHsLJ9Xdqrk8qyWi1vX6m/PxsVC7my8udfI@wFTz87GnxWKXwHXXRiXLD/MY8vbe/n0elmrFj5@9I0Jk@WbdJkvWAIxsXx9dHC0d3JaO311AqVwE4iffdfrG5GswVpECy27bo82BQJfPNvyP0H@hG8Arihs2WA7uGNaVaX4GkICFbyWc/Iyd8ZEUyL2HdHnxfetWPgsgJBpbZsFNSpaew4dDBYm1DpkH3JhNMA9jkwgEfu0qLrZKOyxJYUcwvVhc4Qq8UxmFeBaDrh2T56xxbl@xP3uw7o7sdzOv0dzQZB1YXr1MJxncS4Lbv5e8j2AHvN3zzfHcnu@CeaWfANo6BvE2a8dPH91vJeMBpWNniR@K9vrYhUtl9LY5LgBIdiYRhsORES0oFRkJlME/ip6tRFuWWpawysLsiWkpNnnkamGEv2yFFVM4EwFDxdolDkvFIUoQGWkjNmaWuTbtscxEoPOOobummcxlAb7cog6IFyTBeYU7dHX8BNkA7EKdgVt8IikuRDcaT@uB2WDFodZw8565PM2t6DPCrsfn8F/rHsKXMUGGzPRr@kNlmNF@PYsGJJ0Q1i1zDsrtswZIS9z2uWQXtwhDjS13hs0hKGlRmIdM3TXPWOA21EF9EsYNpTYNyOXNk0EwiRUNK5QNTb4UQhUtKaBuaHNGM4Qt5YGHRjhO9g/qaCaxnU0EvTxOjdysMcCoNjRBHtj0HihsrVJ6PNNzpzlrthPG/SZZNnyxf65UF3w2aXtk@ULC6GNyk4PJCXmRmQcj5ag7TKs1vNBOWlBPw6qyhD7XNBSNFpBy5fR5hwmp6BOaqHumGWyhLB@ZXZ/JfSpVyb0r@945GWCI8y@NGcj@JmV//6f/Snf/H02BPcfCPe48ATe/ki8tcH9T4MQXYe3fx6@FeHtZ/ztbR45OrvjlecmZCIy8PXBEfPJOIcs6hvjWO6x4WJR2s4IirUPvL4k1iE4z1bEmQiPUn8NnIfiAraj@oAaA6VneQ0F9yuW8nnUrnFGRaOVndaYW@Zo@@I3I9y2D0pOfmN9Y03PA5G5ywAh7SHq4FJCjlBVSyBqpEt7UHnXNNnOzg6TfdPoWZWNMmd5ftl4uyq/CwldBliJK@J1BnEgShQDwqoimrJsZHQVo2L/kNbTKCpaLi9B0LYUcgCIit5OsAkD1DlXsAqqh2ONh6SRTIIBBshBh5b1W/zwhgBRDhBx3Li5fLqWR4sDcS11rN5r8WKQ3yDYCYKV5HmVrP6WnQ3PnIY4ZIBBhfnVnCrngPsP55w8ENae2uyWd2V6wzrmhj0@cVxcRLoP1DKlmC@u5vUNNdamZIEK6MUW9BFQQpuBNmha9nt34Nd29w6@ODw6mdm6TZDpabA0S1d3Mmc5LVtvhI70VK0PmPpkP3/y4sl@wMo4VdHcKkJEE6zTZM5LbZrSBam/4asyZ9OmgJmE9MJ9EdNMRm6f1iDMYo9C8zHAXb4abCZVRb2@qTd2qmdOaib5j/OOs0hpK1i5wHXm02EWaTZH5hwEa01P8aQlXwu2KRTl6LCWcFMCf4@8F2@@Ds9tinZgB6taJdobFW6NkrQF610h71qeJ0XbjzlhAb0gawJSdSQ1StCUZubH49QwkZfZI6bE/o2QSYfcRkOnShgODMs92@TQPglobsmhoxBgDH8Q643NLq2JoZHnhEbyICpCq3TLJsOR4QWbcsKQE6tv504DelBwRDuqxVbiLuStZzfLRqU@ZuGWjts2Fmv@oGcPFdzlPNbQQgK5UVTMgL6D24TH6s52Q@zIZsHG6QztvT4aAb@O3AGLrFNPrcB1DCoKezoC5CaOb74Y9QGuTY9jC3sJC5SWHEQGPqYDIuq421jkQeu31iF1rWuNW3YHehpFzYJI@kzXo13bBm47dtIghzmrPsdFg3HGfNJO8xjHjLqh2U7LGiu4qa/UQO6Af/rqzWValWfqAG13F5ubW9P73gNhYQxFq432jE8JhO3tUBAk2872ttb1JdxyA8owpHgy9J6DE/pQpd03BkwZ0cEBPtMYvSpnipP1h57KclXsz66YwzIZGlTDgwJAV0bQNrls2qGp4Dk7Sr4C5Yy@vtPCxwd7wOq6pjXATYmobBkNarugbqApSpVgbARRSoQWOmD4KyFFoHS2kCL@XKZkJdq7C1Bzg6khd7rUAIEXlGtWfRhtlIy1QM7V7e2SKI2kONxmUC125kgMQDtHzAW6KfBXbJoArqEQA6hdz2rZIFAef2k5DrRXBepMH1onM0ZQyTw1Gxxxl43OD6IUUpzEZ2IXBhCaPFdoL33dc0GfWc6XyTZTvoF@/90Zdvxt0fVP8v91XsuXr5XlXmWSB2VMrSrL3YqeWV3JZJadFWXZQXXk4UM06dwsg7ZzrsHAaAxAueWeWob6DNpRZdkpLxs7ynKrUlyhGPAKQ7NriPCtn9eul42b/PJD0Cay4OPx1qks@7Tlv6Bp@g3Qhy1kOZ@FOnONe9fp4DpMftnOZJAGbfkcCfg2f3aSoX7l7CRP1qOyUHLznX4gRpK6SlgSMwfucQYK71Io0ddRoosVNOcBcHSq0Oq8sFu16y9xvSGjqVHL9@P1Kxlyf8EiBBoKJyFkFH7mAjBwrAAT8TVrqCoIk9/@NqVvMCY/2lhV3Myj9UI5k17XYXgI47rUY1BU8yuyJ1@fPc1dMiuXrreNde2bxtHF0dFX6pnCtlk6tXso62vyW7ZdZPf7bLLigg/7XT6p1EpeSuVX9Ieb@fy7d@9AJYdPvapVQXzwj1rPpRt1ZZOx6ubmSnZjayX7OH0eUKUqxaJ6QkMidmbb9sBvteDrdumUSSXFP48eUVow7IR/xv1E@sIRvCCI8E19KpyxnmJnm4axklkrPnbKQN02flaZDk783YKvztbX2R5@/uZ/@5tf/M3P6e8X9P0rg12wD/C5aDP8J/eHVsxtoLvZ/oBHIoDuXSG5MEin11fTJ2/T7P@zzxLTq482//PPD79JDVPVYv6NB89h6pvUxlaKO8EBb6vB22WqmtpBsI2b1CRfqVTAufmf/xeIX/0C8GDIZAd@qusBro1JqpqrUJSPqeoGOPRiEdL9v37yEylVHac@pHRdT03o7zxV0PGz9VB/yNCRlze3ZNd9HBI8jj6BV17Xi2dRecaKG4s29O5COlCuzE0lQckd1iomagM5PgUOzyHdWHr87iljFnS1@CmVHs8w/PnU@7GWg48mmsEYX3LjIAuprUr2nCcf1tVUzDGV4fCXibyH758IJ6WCk9xydaPdiDP90z8sIjpgYiriXZg4m/YLuB6@sKDRs0@Bk1LfVirHQ/x70cS/oxP8@6Fijj2CzxL80T98wlf8XSIf4U0gs5@l36G5Sql6qt5o/KhLfx7@PXPwr/kN/j3/gH8/GuLfqYl/xz/Cv0WZkVI7OzupTOYYVENRZ@/zeQVfTTsXb0HdRXR/rx@2drhx@FhiqVwjk7u5qWtvx5lyWfyD0lQO3/DDXUBW4yaX23lbzWTqRF69KujcyTWqQCsnmX7e7gDizE59Z0c7r1arucbban0nGUnEe/w4g@30MUSsNup1KXWNZVHBnxX8MX38Lcpynl6xs4DeeRtcjJz0EB6MzgHGdyn1buedknmUeVToFS4L@oV@8cI9jP4PD8cQYI8L712v0C109RZIRFawXhUmhcm40HcP9RY4Lfgr9MFpF9rjQqfgFBxdn4wTqBb/9w/d4YtDF7C5EHM4LgwRcaENz87h4QvA14a038OfXSgUxkDkuHAJ/4Ueymc6H4aeb8/VszOpzuR3FnT/mp7WCmltI522G@sbg2/Orm@KG9/Uaci0vt2o43FADZll0@dn9XSjnMr7Z2d5ri7JxTW5TOcF3dycnz@tndbOz/NYtcY7y5nHmdxj@FSqmR3xeJRqVcuPzko5LFReKbXzVH7n0Vl1NYfujQyUXBH8dvKZT/xEKOFZXTqT0uzqzZs3@H1zdXnFXeTgfmdvwlD8eZMHL@5CL/ggaH5e/ISDgf75D/TfOvz/1/@LV0ypN1TGlOubHYU@Kv6p6vXN9Y34raqKIl6UHfhDD3jHKNc3VXQS0DW46oraUG9uuB/8KuoOR1jFNHaqFDkCvEaJfs3TPUuXQfOrLCtikufsbFwoqOUm@IR2aeMjzReoZVpSsdzEOR4YJegrKoGsr5XLa8K9uVUubwm3vrFRLq@EUAV4EU4AsnzDLGN1L6dUJIGPGRRGp7LJ@tm42GZFGe0yyrYKwzJ9FQf/G@tMrVY31sFjY0vNKQW02/AoZ/JgMDiTNbJUa7Q1qVKpeZ4xQeuUsgZIlO31SuVMNrzzM7lebGDc9dz2BnO93PaqKqvqW31nB9LAJIoqeMvpsex6aaidzE@nblLEJLa2rirNiaWubShbmW3xV1mC4lLk1fQqjnHSRrpef7yyurK5Vn/UWGEr@GUrys5ZtbFIY1DTKRAlQduv6CQyGYqA8rVR0W8q10YJbQI3ZVOcd9ZzO8x4@HB1@@NHfauA0IBAhk8QFTykStPqANHwNmAlfaW4upRfH3@2sVdgSx9X8FOv17eKW5kVkDIr29uNRoN8Py5JZZz14iPYXJpLKba1TYWWglFjvT9uN@hYlEqurm@sN3Koebwft1cgJX1zNbUiDWgVymaBtXD@zmNuu70Enl3DZ02cavWtXi84Le7K9XqtK7tlLUmpo@e13b3TbHEHUBb3a7vZ4smrJykdX9ejdwpexffjvdrTw1cQ4ej5Xu1k7/OD13uvjsDfh/5N8i349I8Ma2SdW1ej0RW@n1v02bV94/17YzA4h8ozGLe//9VPv//Vf/v9r3/2/a9/@v2vf/Gb737xU/j@BXx/xp8/@7fb6/j7m@/@@f/4/Z/9Gjz/Cr7/Ab7//jff/cuf8C@9/zV8/4@Y31@LbwyOf6FoANsf/ea7n//5b777p7@E778S319Of7//k3/H//9P8YfOX3//J3@NP@Llpz8DhH/3l7/C/5//5d/9h1/h///0r//uL//F3/3RvyHHn3LH//2v/i3//dvf@@nf/uM//tvf@27B709v/f3uHv7f/QP43J/O@@C5T74@1ee7H0TP78KNKBWqVL/4w@//5e9Dbf0T/vZP4A3@w6A/CF8SIfzlD6IXwPA/zIn0h7/57o//PHz7/SRgIgyQ/AGE/Vki7A@@/9VPvv/z/@b7X/3p97/6IxRPubXtbC2b0@8YigDg@j3gEHDjPnAAqAujwJJUpCf@CE@2RK7xirS@ioOFHP9kuOfHZVQD2dlHaR3eMx/zqBmy/EcReoY7eHUIXV2j0AKosQUMXcfXIJQdy3pRPmbnKwzNPI@C0TMfYHBCVj4@ZgAMkRkEfybrW7IAfMQJ/cjjZD7Gc5bBmBS@FBIOXxH6iLIq4ieGZzvv3lWqCPAYgnfgnTzxF1/A5wmMASr4gUd1i1WkLNuq4FFhCFiBdwpHJ70DLrwepCI9ZU9wyIXeT4FD3LDBxtI79o5DMoTdojgShH8LHk@4P2FDVN9K4JXhPk/h@a2AH0uED/@FjQTd@A0C4CfDuB@8ZhBJJmAT/9mpShyOCTtLZG4JeYqDRoK2lo9IRV55ugK/OvzvLfkSJpEZ4z@LkhEJZCRgUyYbFG0i7UzkJYWvmZnUgxjSVFgmCmOUZiaJKsNmEN4WmPCWpiOyuVgEBQtDp7IZhM5JMQhNzUYJg@IMymSSDMOYyUxlpAyuel4Ria5kVtAYzlY@9SNoogTmsuOWT5zfK1HO43gj6iOsRC@PkCHYKG0I4mo7zaeBvr3GVEmhM2dVGp9bgwE8X/idJ@6YKYWsLGf1jW1ulhbD96/dUqnyrb62KcGT3kd43K04eBUqMF6Bou3AByiQqtc5dO6gE3S8DalaFXOCTJeqJ3unEOH0kOnFgsbqhcb12mZxbX1tvbi6sbG@WdTXNrbXNta3Vgt6YaOwXizq22tr21vbmzdA0GMQ1dnSSnN9p/qPZj7/1T@a95nvix@p@hUba@zo6Ee5G6k6zuXyRSK5oq9vlicVIIS8pCqpr1y1nVznfJ/h8lzpjHTma1wKBKRJ1zlszQ/gw6QHEnsAXvABzDgjwsRM9MFhWcxX4mHifM5S1te3ZWD1meW0ODZpEP9IWHAP17bZQ5071zciZwGd0ikeu/8SEoBycNhzXJA4dNmpyxe@PbHMBRC7XX5xzq7ngq7@w2GeGM4FD3pq47Fr5jAMembgoSp@3x52F0C8GvRxi4nl/YNh2Os3gUA02nKAJ/Dj9Vx3HsAme3W0IJcvwh1UOP1JW6gA/Pjg82ensefpXm33mbTBnhy@fDr1WBdA6@z53v5p@LrJQ4Oo6yGKr/eeP59@FQ8cdS2x9c1sVtM0@MFnlj701JbfBiC6tlipkTcKsqUVsnr2fGLB@Os6l7vp2E1L3wBtY01OwYAPj10@4QdLD2EoPG5TY@i5/sqWnk6bRsfqs3EFmrAOtRwXxXbcHgxEYUC9XNgtgPbCVqFO5z@ieevckl7gyrFtne8wsH3pGQz9@niGL271HUqe1QIyrhzaPNHE@zJGA7bQEx7ohU7P7nRBvF25IYAPtbVpGAy@n/oBHFb8M7zdY8jTIL@ZkN4suHQVWsXeBCaw0BTGm/wbXNNLG3uCSXh/aHh4Q9wpilq6RIXhLtImnjtOm7NQg6F9lHRKuAWCd1uScOLRbrOCpKHwKha3t9a3tleLW9mt7a21dRiPr2f1Ylbf3NrchlpQ0Lf0ja31bT27tba9ugZiF0LXtzelFIgmu53PQ7eiyzI9bcfEEx538KhMV@tWpVTLamNDYWOlpbJUK/QYbTF5deuswCCiLOHa1pVxRS6u4cLzVZ3psiQbzGSp/f3dwv6@LD/BF7Sd7hZkuYUv61uFwuYTWbYoZBe6hiJE6uLb3gYaWWXZxpfd2v4@YniPL8UtxCHLFzyEv/SCl00Ac/BldRURMFn@JkRXAOQup2iLYg35S6HwZFeWR5w83NIGcDX@tkbE7uELBmCkfR6yC2Gy/HkQCdqDDGo8wYmkngX5rdVk@YC/1GqI4gvK/DrP1Jf4UqMPRPLgDeq9LHfA0fEsy5HlJjix9suyCS5zYoBfH1x4WoQzNGR5wvOBOZHlMUEb5oUsnwf@kA7Q8@yZ0R22rA7/TDz@NCHoAILs8Whvv/n5581Op@lNanufH1PQF188M95PRl6z0xQRm@fwcTEWBF30J9MfC4POz43e/KAvIciZCjqfnFtE4bnxDVAmPh1MqH/@BQZ9AUHz7GYCIXz6ANzEz5M@PJ8YTR4UfCiInuNmUy5jlcWm01ao4hpZejSZeo0CTTEekaAsoZR026A8jbbU3Pqj0Za8sSmXVuApP5JXwTlWCukCY3L6TJbV@nbjkby5LpfSjx7l0g/1R0ze3JZL8uamrJZvUMAq6nVbGWfHlQJ45PM72I6x5cET9BGhTJxa46H2zMJVLmYu9ybx2dl5A3C4cxN3yb0c9WE8dEWiA5fKB8uazytPQE4Uyg5u37XwdXmcGkvVljE0YPz25HpUKgnYm3KnUkcEH/FnJye/qb6RGyye7vpmAah65ZjFzZ2d@tXHBihVFb08SUF/UNwqj/G5uRZXp5Z7hj9c1jeLpfpouZ7TG0tLhY@dHfnHVUJ9A5llcTsmCKoy@AWs4KItFE4QA3c7wDeXkzB8UBHlIjMFb3vgZkolnd4sptNqugwRl8BbMJwKNCgRGYQhlMh2ETSzsmcNR6AHFMo3M0l6FyWSzLgFDbGXmLwB2hx4A4jEdcYNXUrdSC08I3JtW0pdSzfXNzvVoBP@kk0mRiYYb7OHjHUyy9JyGqlKryaHlrVKrXNcKwdvu1Iqt@quuanl5WUptXNalVflQ@08nMyp5mmO7gxn7HCOTjs731nK/KCZnpxWfcynRKugzbM89NS4V62FNw5yq/zWOjKqw/xU5gd@IBGpgmwry7KcklPYbs2eO8J1DjtnPEM736bIas@Ortsjh9aEll5g@RklrqXUG@q3L@3e9dZqrkrrmBRoQTdUYuYhTdxLKccVTrQpD6EVKaCDr8s42rHY4GT77ebbrbcvXh2@OtxnjwulrdIWZzitpHiczeppPQ0F@Bg6R/t4T0oNPrrr@rfOF@VUaZBeXUuvJgrtrCL28CpYG5U6TozUVxuNOoxkGrT2R29UKsVH@vpWZq2kb6qpKm4nLG4iq9EFLTS3mmqkOJI1AGjwVXRFPVXNC299U1dTfo6/QZT1lC@ltl68Q1tPcCueXSRXPs8JW77ZuYH/6k0dxmo3NGS7oX/@c3PDw@GfwMM3/og@McA4TBT@w6qcdp5qfJvb4f87@LN7yPMqb0Bhpd5VqlAR3p6/PU/h3LFcXMdNW5m8GDbxloMK14pDf5a/gn9vI48V0BFXwjd43Vlh61UdYq3k8/kz9UdF0Ji2tze2NlLSb4Frt6wAh9BwSWTbguEKSNw5ayJrnv3CwPWiTrguEhwvRh/wGpPHwf2HgXLFULvCRb@oXsX9hMYV86JrQ5N@Ez@P27bQV5LQZdNtvKxN1RDF6pB2GrEVPJwG95ar0rX0AHCNzCHt@IKfsiQ9wG1@@KoEcFn20B@qaLwrqNKDB0I8@kPNH54jcowkPHN6WbqRkD1Gq@UzukgIJ9/4hnQD9yy5A36MW2/CeCSf7nrhmmJ4HUCM4BXW5lRAblYYpUiUY@Z48g84WHPURlL2D57vQRwYdLdpdaKILXtNvKWLsrfUVlko5YEHeNdMRXCKwBEQ0IEnVwTUPu56N6lJswzTMbxNqxwBKsv0LFGSZW0RsY6vDYiO6Nsg1XxAzFNXeA7YyrlIVuRB0EOZABZi7qinoltgvI6ZFaWHR6HjPPF1sFNQwVC2w4pqbLck4YLC4DfrUkSz3xJXBlUiNhM2vZGFoi3zLZFKCCd8IkbdSCvDbL/Mi2pQlr5UTFBcXE8pf9t/@NB8O6j3G2W1XxniM5PpQwd6odgcZGVY6VegegzqdqM8rGcydqPSV79U8B0v9sLeVmhdviryBjl3KkALrhr11eyHupP71mlk9@tOBkgeZVd@XPmQNSoFVJyydkXP9rLfgAbC8wFpDisfMk7Z2IEvrvRN7FYFZSFjlBNeGOVC6VU@1I0GamI9iJjJ7ENmgE6/3stkGiok3oPA2Yjl3sOHRqZXHZd7uZyKUG9XH@3Xh@BoZCr4XlKMnfGjD/URxC8p8KxAMj0ViId4gtc3Ie1AXxl4zMs0Ip3TSIriGMjrVyorP3608uOVytLSh/o4129kOftLhag2IPFjJL4c2w@srPxYZVMsodl@Rf7MLn2mreCmTjuTASZnB7GYnMKVH0PIIJMJqL5BeXkaH8BiDRMbCPl2TbpkgTaF0ICVhq78ViEUFzXftG0Bzo91GNh4SAEeUJSl67gMgsAwcQExBp6NHz2SgqTFnjVIGYULDJUNtBfQNZS4BZgOvGD8LKa75Os8MRzI3HCkS1dDwZh6dSPWXEk0UYPzPbOOICgGrgs3ZS6x@E5FEDYkPQCGpAfC5VCKIJOEnBCQFREIpRUUEMRCOdHm54jRUUoon/AutbDlgwjhZEBjnkOGnX1fIdkE9ckGF7N3KD1wQFORHkAmkAbMg91gVRBk7OFDJl53KkwvbmJfgGAI9z6jI9AMpZD4PSgFHEjle6ijKA8pEaDtAYbgNvBEQmu/W0LiiAcFImTeZ/lJDxqd9KCMHJ@fjIJ8UzkZWBYPHrzPVNYEQfBPIweID2E3v02J7r7Edg9fHL063Tt@UTuBXxgnbsVv3Asuw525CnOAV1w2bYd2k5rGsW59/YXJmIJjJbwxAe@6brEvXj1nxeLLp1k8xxhYn@LGeOhQSyEmy6f7ZHzN9Tr5K/vCzu8lDhrFa4lp46pfoltoxcpWiw5boOutw/NaouNafLTdQWcuDl9NXFvWt3xf3PCZC25Lp5Pv6OSaPh7AAq1Q3AhKe4ISW/BxIUiWtmZ5dsemK7C7HEEiPl3tNeTRqX1IeJMnjVmhRkvbW4VCiRWy6NADRzFwrAaOtcCxHjg2Asdm4NgKHNvCoQeYdY4ZxrWrqxuRczNybkXO7dC5VoicEYa1YuRcjZxrkXM9ckaprYWpbWwRXpYKuElN1/IwTF/bCsLIHDAkz3VAo097rgGhxRlIiL424wnpbSU9N7cLIqGD/CECFYsb0TtInwC2onCqspyOLE@ZvwlP6KskPsyjCrvneSCV9sZ4dTFUOrXE8KQFScIj0syeZYAyYA1BS6nsQ/231BL1QUNvUoqOmUAMFT18h@h48RvE0en2bV595gQX5wVzbMW52PiJWSxkTOzADUEkp7KU6Gk5xrWEXxzrEgpY5OgCiCKHwDJIns8RpHnqjeYmuXp7kgmEc5OcIYrjXZ8XC3mjEPJKEJX6f8JWCdLjeopFpQ1qAMaEQqc6MFWgeFBX5Vovyb/57pf/M/vNdz//Nfv@z379//z7/x7d/w5//lc8iKIYAvzs54yWn8DPv2C02IQWvkSRCH61JH//y1/B63/3b9j3P/05D/rjP5ezayEiCEGvKOYv/gn@/D7@/O9ydj0E/MUfckCMImdvpIRqpQDUz/6KMUgNsYTIfvkXjMkZUDAUUfPqvI03YofycAQhG@rkakyH81@8sRZ4XFAzMuAVb3r0lsECUGPIPQOPc4vaHqgz3OSIUto0zC6ebyG8XB/1HxNVGNfXOlDfrlqg9AizRBpy/3usxNIZhEELC55LVuEyXORf5FuOQhE2I@eBOry0UaCi@3xDSmB4K0H9ppHAxNdw2EIjUp3XEcHflxZ0E0EHIgc1i@4nlURaQWw0y4ir3unC2mCoi5UWuyF@rhfd0yqJAxj0WIIJcTNVbJDKtA8MGaOTeeJRycPqD/BkmUrEb2QsvhAXstPoopITzWbvcH@qweCnCSrmRVwihQlVmCzfAYucFvAqalyrSXhOrwCoF0qrjcQZP/OA5a@@@kqWYn4FrENeSyEMsUxxkREG6cmgYiyoGAuy2wInyZr1YnGKBuo4UC4mT7ri0WIiKhktqlzYcoJyQDJgLMgNotl2b@R3K7OoSSInhd0s8hhKvVER7eTMIZlTZbI6EwFwJuNUpstyPurCDMxsQc2PidxO@CRKazGmRJxYoyDuSdNcCktO355XcskEb0GtNzL3TKhY@B0Tyt0zoY31uxOaLlaMm0C/mL93i51ATIQSPkLGG34q0UFh1/hLqHqROEKKPXIqKgx5amLI07xymRIMPzr2sDtq0jAG/PPBxQX5Zs9t5vs4yvHwspLwOgMcxOCRTdw88HjgwpDDRS04GCoZDnslwBPDDn5VcsdxPcuPH54kbk920nimlel2HOjVsniBgn1hiTu0LXGoabJfCXs2oYXiEdUw9EHUnFGoeZ6f2449PD8H5bPXViMG4qtm4p7/tGRCRHDF4iuhans4UFy8CGao3o2T9F0e7dQ2L5TDgQhMQyI1BgM60@rB4It18cLx4PZozCK/ghw00uZQocOau27f7ViOi8d5Yewp9AcRbiTIGAyIliwzssyMUSQG0YqZNVQR9ctPjsq@LCqGGsYvJhEkmJFl3jSPkbPenOTOFybHowXpnXw6vSdxek9up7dte/5wmmbyRGsPPj8t6VUlwgCAERmrd5ORFcdozpCTICX09lEvogj3JrFFC6JaSGkNQGsCXGtD/ciGbz7t7heEv17E/9sLMIi@d9/iI2X2ZALypk9309MQzQ8mxxUAP1DVaMFkLLmwaj@9Z1pioEMjvCyTSXA5eHQENMzBwHKiy8EDxHfUeVzWNFPvaa1ThQfOocm7zLKL4uIienresnrGxGopAjIbwxvk@NgyWiSv7pdxFHQk9GAMQIbMQlZPqGJ0xA8BlRZUGSN7qaqLqxUHscPaQ5NxROHBYv6R4W5aNKMRtMLnQFwPJGiKzqel44QHk8GEHwvWo/P6AjnK@x9eki9dcSDgrQwBPvBL7/VslKx6m/g8VsIs3aNHCGG1ZJbpcI2g23JBG58pw09j0d05JStDGKkSlHJCO1lU4vZtJR6rFUGd5FrJ/arkXZXu3nUuVtU4skiE7X5aFzKDedfo9UxTiWPkPreWmOvMyAT0wxJznQW9yvkcgRrGJEk3xAtuK1y/UCUbnAfwvITna3giQhiDnvMKFeQN9drA5EUhfWMQ01qET91EXTTGRTU@jxiDkgI3GnJvwjTNhWmaM2maiTTDFpBMMgYkmYkkRSlg8dxWBD2rPVwgnTEIR@7wuE1sw8dxDQ/nXq/TdrpkZ1n6Ml0CgZy20qU9BYRyupUuPSWHny6dkOMiXfoSHFHbSn9Ml4JmgQAevJLjMfoLEY7vZrq0q6g30hAP5w7S1dKlsEwB5hF/JY7ccPNqU8z6u6FV1bKyXKnMMqwxPjxczFa9kaVvAf754bv8tHgIXKqw4goB4wAk0WnEegyeDnQbWs@9sjxlXvdRCkxTwr4R2VAgPFOJGVWwloxIHqVT6aQw4oRhKBkf4QkEotwszaeI6TMjs7vIEalDDaVCTqZP3NNIH2gpFF4H4LgRpxfFD8oriYIX4P3oxMiL6JwhJ0iOKMLFAOocspCp79K3ZArLeur8cF768RKatRFgIeYCEF5KhDYm00GHQ92UEhu4g2QloVCc7bPjcfAjGiXW3qloJBVEy1wQTN4iZygY4o1fvS07sXhIWkIEYWC90OCtLOwXSBZjUCTrYpoqb3xAQkzmtOjcRAur7VPhJDgubrLUVyzqhoK4PEmSXEkxCZE13Dg/MoY89WheBrfTf9rwNYg5xjtiFEQQixmmwuWr@wn6u8v190ChDpgwlcA8xXp@VzqrXt/ay05R3ouSnS1ADMyyp@pc5ShMIWI5jA5imvltdW1GxR85gZLPEw2xT2n7AdvCMcEdfJseW3BcqCV4l0nPCzTMXhQXM2pWI@ldaoHSomFKAg/PeEhplLXbaeUZn1fEGIJ9NDw@uYC9ZAHHCw/xUQa8KZbzVo5bvmieImzbdPpdNHPBZx1cXCUWnngf8wRxT@vXwiVa4HF4fvz08OXzr6HT3dzcVGenIrDVQtyoH5dunSYIhy3FLJ4bi3v2aO1E1/WGS2eOPLukjDxAGTBo3oZXP9HGVSHLYvJ8qu1CPA4b46jAdRE1AyMhlVDVMbDLtgVf@cWayoohkATqLfA7S6M1nDXC2oETOufn1H2dn@PinPNz0Yth0YTTSL9NMXFmopRKrmEiPcufOZIRh/2jPm2RCsxu4rBFvvoED0A7GAaxw1gjZ2gHSxzQKkR7MoMZfGVVR5vEQTv0ITpwKYZSXMOBa3EdTx/hsRAazZ20oFKks8TVG7xGxx@4Dp0aTyfxkrKOl/r4gcGVyB45VwYt/uCp0KEpMYr4MqxgNsx1@A03Po@Lm0HJcBzwJsusjkbzPMVtGGhc2AN@mHi44MNXKRIRTCuzgMfNntUHkk6gxs6xIb@wodJ09@1OB6pPXtwRy5e1nBoQNee2c7vBIZkp9tro2eGtIWIlGN3@I6y/wE4lccqpz4oboENtZ4Gz0RcYi4tjGJ5kWqClWQQF3014bHLnVjYWd0mZqLPPVX1JOccS5ZvvbQ/vgb00nBh/6fMxbogWU5TU6mPzlMBcRxyOmMbTEcMDNiVx0nKFpik1XKI2UOSUHJy8iU5p4FkornM6Xz9h9MzgSFAFD6MtSQ8ckkC4FIyZfJENaLoOam80z6aGa1Md9hlbLUp0FZJLVmZOAODgU3wJ7BAGUTEffJmfkDTyZy35M5xVlB6kUCjy6ofxg9qNbrrlIqrebEmgw/WuYgqTN4vgZT32gq2DX14EWcfRyAZQOIeSJUXOANqMrMocdRh/OrqYJnnARfQspizO1D0QrAYsv/3k9duW5zkEJl26UJH7Lh4/y9cel29ZDUzLgXHNYWIxMBIdX93ZFove@H2aWfkVLtsq8USow9HwOGaU9@VpgZ/TgzWe9MDF1WyFtjS3E72T7GHkkIwl27mNAOqGqKKjmKI1Y5/5JfgCDdkAJbCJljkoxBv1TtqII7j4ms5ia5Rj/ZCix6lBAts@yKM28DMr0/0lDyEi9cvQSarzdK1COREfiPMHDi3/lnOaTFHFUmXElETBSxP9wwWzEq2SD@TeLRdMGHl9q7CxTYuumZMdZvv17UZ2xazIzBrahtP3R95V66Ljdi9Bw2CD982xOfnwDWPrawx3phQf8nMD9I0KbgRR2CadvLFdoD0hwbkfdPrEmcwYbR/GU0TSjIW7lMpLeHgAfLL4U5LLM7WUrfSDWshXXvfrG42KUymU@3WnUXYyGXWYqQwzekZBj4e6WgZBzW019WGDllLmV9iLYL0jHr@MBlm3zY5cx@y6aZ/RrdzxiUDaExY0oL4xiLenSxiquF7cp431yegnGuKsF91oORXTdgO44WRgoRgNl4r2XKi/@PNgtLFWng3HHD54gOuay0KhjWfgWhqMmj3bBPFE/ES9BNc4lkpipb7JsN6C7EI/m3tyWqADUzC4HISa7mAiItsc5DzIy04MZVXBrk/N3gcygGpCnTzHyzI8AOMgnL0JcAaoqQdTOVXofm45Ye@EmyvUMi49Z0tBWLANA@Gx3tBmiHPQGWnrBDx2mAClhclMFcuAybdu40oE0u@qaR704P2oPyD1QOP0Co7gHXXnA8P2wpiaP8ILKhWmIzPsgGgsAXTc4Ga@S9BG40UTlAVaI2hGHPOD@I7oOHcg2DTwcmOQjTgjhPhaLsV5wG9PVKDD5NYuToaIS9lQRVED4/BEvfQgXWJknCiDF3U/5VjoewjFvC4I7kNw3xh2FwR3EffIXxTsQTDeqbgg2IZgvlBlfrgL4VwRWwAwRNMbVNfzoXs@NOyewldZ4/rsGy6wFZbJBIwNqwDjBcPLIxmfifXqbImXDq9sieoF7ZOqFQfAKq2IxoPvUW2hUDzqQ@H1IpYm5wm7ZncmJixWwOJzSgnELqavriTwsxgB0P5AlLLZ8CBxXtphRhP1R@P3akHwDsj8jx9vo0xUxGT90xtB7eMlhMbRWA45tyI8/HK2qFx5pA8i0vw4Yj1/XLoFmmuUj6BRFiMRwttW1K7bNuiWEFVFLSfyxnGoyh5FPnW/wUqh9Ij4yJvF3XwsztQeHKZSi8yyZuQ0789VA@s9xDSgR25GwgI3bxnlGXb6IXQuCV0F6JCbU/XMTNQZ0Uo/NbP3y00K6KNGTbwpc0FrgmpYFQTOIc/g5RqXCRzZcrrE/fE2LzuJzF6AjG9yPAcEwx2gAXu2QIwHfaLtaHyhEMj5QnEtS3Z/DnITsSkQVvfh099D40LGiS57hBecJEUSm8OaGfAw38iv6nSTm8oel/TzM1fnK83Sj9JII5utT1TrHkEvWWIFFu6mKbObu@XQD@PMdVR8CX3HVxbLiqDQg5p4nyp4s4DRd1ayZBaKDZbgOJJAkuGOLol2hs7vlKL5jvPAJ7CF8ba9UANDqsrJcKSZIwwCQFGOx8oKnasaiU6xJfZ8GCg32UgLw3vFeK0Alb0sxcU5Duf2qfOO@4b7eYgj8RBcXogaphdQZrcD3RbU4CCeZp5jMXMmIz@hTXdct6UECpNQGAhDsGwagLJ8j1GoVnH1MkoekhNKL@uIpddBv1sGnyXhRf1Kma5dD/QzJGKlQ82mjM0mpt/YPl17R@HYG0FSwZQQ2pK49GGlaX@EDlWgB3MjBRIfN4rRdmIh56knTogHeddw0G5HB5HR0HpHRv@wIBCmCgPtaNMxlcHNHCsD31gtthxfx4cudtnWUCcOC12M2mGYHlKzsyNjMtF5Gr9NLeVHvpdv2k7eci5BqW5OpFRo3irh1aK5LbTe4gWhQpqQsZwMQlBNoKQwNc2xrpTwwlG0PUh8oyAZkHQJj5UgY37PumyB1s@X0Q9cf0y/ExgsFLTRYOhSiEiINhSyj/bHaJN7gaZ2xYhBkLNDeCIYBSd9uO@E261yOleQdDwyQ42hqGNMErjymSxj@SGhwuxXb0i@ZhlmF4nAuveRD6eguKgm30h@UPS4AQ5ZgTOK4Ozxpb8DsuNhEqSd@BN6h@zju44O7kOWSKz3Ypwikb0WQ/AGcKzkaJbD@DvAAM74ByenT/eOjzVujeP2mxJOPXAzM67boF2E4ipxYWXFKQTcw8kL5QFmFnHz9CoRcpK/xCNMVrAJm8IVspPzCjeJ8hzkdHqbyUYIr3JwYgnNQYs3H3lZEEutB6BHIe@iaEosWi6IFgDHWPHgTm4Ypomrc19YfRco3rV6PSCa8@JBxA50IkeC9DNh@n4d02yExPPw3Ex4LhGu8XBOVASlmV0vAirFgeTUdQR3w@QILDuTVoVBpg9e0pYfzfVidJdvg/U1GKTZEXA1LEpeK8OAnURALhbydk7p85ClRJywgofhdR4u6ndRlHxIZQL2cTJ9fEqigCxaGCvWkUzVUs2xe4@4@TEMIQnLcK8Lj47lTdWON0phEBHiJAdiAm@Fx2ZbrURYMnogcajNyNWdx7ImTFKPlGkyuMF7pmHNaSMxLlGaGWLcmHoSSIeCl2IoCCdWNBa03GoQeSIiT2JoEWopSFYKtm8nGzhkbbqJV9CE/hF/gsaeJC6AS80PfMApH/PM84mwJINI6C7J89mUlCZDb2RxT5GpW3qRKO3JNMb5QuKliyNQs4uSIkzT4tN1bXfktJZCOREXFIGkmOF7GCI4HQHoQfVdVIQYeCP9Nr8ifW70QSvsWWNWQ53aoIOWpMRcKF4V7uOZYnhIJvNHg0HPFpvt2BXNtomjiIrrODEUYYwpDZp0gKt2OHwWXWLuEiJp7BAxX9n8Sm4R4I86HX6/MsMLHEG04q3p9lCTas6EX/2Me9OKfEZSXNqOArgHw74YEbzkeOsJr9PWpOAEHp7VNm/f4i5wnJXDe52hSytJ0o9Gtnmx@zkrFgqbemFVj7EsMFUXtNU1ukE6UJGCgGJBLxTW9TVJ2nUHE77eRDFVxLWWQ4RZ9hw7@tdQN/G@c8eSatBjEKCP17Nb3qXV0iTp2GqRDbg5Io5gVaYbzJ1g8z36gG6FhxDhHeR@ll80DjUMn9g/8wMFTFrtnJVwindgeX17yCeC3Usbr0YPp7Xbbq/nXpEhGmeUOT8wUt8aAlNWVJYkiQ4LELSQ7kJ7@IEbhrgH2mi6l3S4h2AD6Kk2nolE87MS7mxFDPHE@CWyMUogPbNn2H2sTnMIwK0vEQcCAiBrrZFp3UqDRER8Ig3BBdct1xzhcQlGUDJ5kH4utRVo7pZng/SNGEylQtFitEMBnz47OGEnh/unb2rHewzcR8eHrw@e7j1lT75mp8/22O7h0dd0iix7dvgcpMsJq718Cr4vT48Pnrw6PQQPuXYCMWUKkGovv2Z7Xx0d752csMNjdvDi6PkBYAP0x7WXpwd7J1l28HL3@SvorD/PMsDAXh6esucHLw5OAez0MEupBtGkKB473Gcv9o53n8Fr7cnB84PTrynF/YPTl5jYPqRWY0e149OD3VfPa8fs6NXx0eHJHsOMSU8PTnaf1w5e7D3VIH1Ik@293nt5yk6e1Z4/n8ro4ZuXe8dIfCKXT/aAytqT53uUEuXz6cHx3u4pZihy7QLzgMDnWXZytLd7gI69r/YgO7Xjr7MC6cnej14BEASyp7UXtc8hc5JyB1egXHZfHe@9QKKBEyevnpycHpy@Ot1jnx8ePiVen@wdvz7Y3TspM@n54Qkx7NXJXpbhVS6UNOAAbkE4uJ@8Ojkgvh28PIU@49XR6cHhSxUK@Q0wBqisQdSnxODDlzy3wKTD468RK/KBCiDL3jzbA/9j5Clxq4ZcOAGu7Z7GwSBBYOJpPJvs5d7nzw8@33u5u4fBh4jmzcHJngoFdnCCAIAT031Tg0RfUa6xnIAu7oTKKgU1N0vFyQ72We3p6wOkXEBDDTg5ELWF2Lb7TPBcw7Nr50653TqBNzvLJ0wht5/cs3v4dA80Pn6gnxz5v4JOZys5eZcIg44mDIRXMQtKfdV5y2qOOue203ZxaB5G4zPYfb@TxZMqVabg/Tu3nAgvJsopQip1fv66dg7j3JPzczV7n5gJMu6KIbbG3walijz2XKNFw/yEbSnOqOpDcQBPlp@GEbe1PAyNDyrL51uWiIYLSRBxYCYSJ0UBshZKRlphYjgsliRNMSdtRXSM2bSxKJjedH34cT5GL7xviHmAcObrFvJ5HMMSGXgcHQvph0TopDZxXButA7DblKTmW9ZFRynEk8MhvzBQqUEcgh3CMLCjqHdEb1qdqei56fhELK4AImUlOKMnODuH37yNb4JlTJSL5lHOFG7ao4caUEMJgVKo8qRoeZFYfaI85NFx0ze3Farl8HwXOqPtRe2rgzc4mCsU18pT/s9Cf962cCkgHjgI/V2d4jXo8azBAaCB2Tj8ApbYEz6lms/H4oBWRvpkCIwHCHUR6MpuQZ@KXXXXom4djy3iZzjE40Nn7NnjOPUghj8/rr148mp/HyQnUru2tb65UZbEMUje8Kssf36N6dChushd0KKvbFDTKCjWSnZB79mfOcEwduQilh4C4qnlQaGRJ948Hm5n5joCP/SMm4Ewuz4e@@TgyWcyntzkyQwXTVpLUlBf57ZMUQGURFZVzE3fGJOGb4CqRHXA5FuXexMqtTH@IO6w@QdNPMyQqECiiln9wXACNRcGFyT35P1gFSiNbWiJF4JoclCPB0awBokzBmUmLY3FJZL0Jup2rBRBr8WCxvZKxU4xgYilaSqCk/PoHExI4sj1gxbMPW3w@UrUN3B@LU5sxCA8f6s2PAE27ocxc8GJitzmLBqGwNyoVqCIHj4MU9phaEhVBVHc/p88zy/eGogUvqCBTSEOVh6FfA5DyAj9OK2ya15T8agVxFMWNVa8Q82dlx2BpRycUyPeg2P9GMcVnfJHXldhGlIA8nUAErIzwabfiR@E/78gT@bg34EBJ2CPuEVy2HZG1j05SVg5r2D0Skyxr4IVY7FlahE3415fR2hu4gXTDTMmluGN@cQSsECUziTw@Jqf86rMYQBWcrRrxNsvnqpAjbhrwMjpMbXdB3ym33PM/kAJTkkNuooZvI0s6VzZYIkcvqh8Cr/AYsk9x0PvHtPmW5IZOOACKdacsM98mePI6CRzMNP5FTJ6hK2cqiayQQ9aeFSdCqJpBY1/LFYYRb1MKwi9AVV08Qms4XQIHvSYEPjBDEggQGjtUzzDgm2QZhUJnZtvXH5PVn4menELxWab98vslFZP@0abxszYFYmlzrimGpNEPJ@1xEGaTWt4hd1Fj2OnJd4RNqZ8RqvMMRFhiwzViED4qhpwnTrZq5B6MlNifQ2pf@VcOHhhh8VNXAGEljiWM74vXmMvDDqhs3e/fMtR4hlkazWZ/oFDy95NPl@JpjkauUMqONL/zI84AhrnFWqX0A9FXDLMC/SUgzpqX@XsMTworZzIeXDQJIwZ6BjheUr/zcIBAdaVqTWwTD5zQiNSiXdklc8C9QVdvO2Grq/RJezMFcgUEAc@uGBWqEFIMupNuEhztrURfeFeh6KUosWnJdCcrq60pjHqG07b6Nu9Ca06fe92nbzvjPyBNpjg/aFJayBdSAJwQPvQYm9sp@Ve@ewJNAc0JJ28fHVylDT8xSxfu9zyxdgXkAZ7QilLM@jbuJHFd9tDKBqrzCbiCiovMveQnVBYWsisNUEP3C3kUQWCdPuhZvz5y1fsc8uxPNAHj2jNJXtum5YD4gOUKVqF6Xe5pEHwfUz9RKTO9lF3IctOmVk2GXVC254kEhDYsli1FGiKQLAnzrpG2/wEqnrMJqjNZjjKVyswKnXdgdisgUZTVDa5ibM96mUlPFD7zcHpMxyM84E52WagWwtsfWhL5KpTnxtrITOe4QwnwBRp2ngDZN9lu9EY7dUAjNJidtKgro/X/rTQ7NfzIat4f5iQAtSDQFO17Es8wZfMcPcpI1pnK8xmEd/KYtNrVlyCI0RHovSkqPSyeJC7lmXr2@zUwrrLjnqGCSMsdjLC6KuroAc@cf0hgr6oMVYo6rqe01fRRPvqpKZRQ8BvcKyrJB28ODo8PgVGinOLgooR9pnIfDpJla/GAnbk8DxVyP07FMgBPEjM4jtiHqrgweEKcpnPWMglGcreNNDcCzn0k@owmWTRJO96dJorbtaBKpRojpCqf4XCl0@NUEox7Fk6T1acCMu7lpBO2mJJEd4hbT2oVz2cD31HkckPBIA1Jj@I5dHIoCXOIoIy6Vv9kHp7GPTuBgeQpg@iDRnGbalQOdLZNGpJwD01jqdl4RoJH4906vuXpgeyxbiEKodLWIIdS1BnSDapYW6Mpt2zoQ0AXWbXxQ6Hi6ugIMgEET@mVqISDw9AxA6JaJlzhBS0rpbbD0E5VZIU7tAT/gN/Yros1YFhNo60/IFltej4qtGAn8@E4Rq08h70HHzvXik6uElKFWjdpAfCBs/JA9k36uGGftyA2eRlLgW5gVoV7Pk87eKwniOCHJ0MqZHiMbrKnBF2luE8r0rFbkCFwLgqMmLB7ktAMcjipBRQBeVNFYJcVF2ydG0Vlff05kyMSCdE@oNkAOLis7pWMiBAj3kXzhkAXkkrIQFT@z4DYvieJe5O2MCSL5hfXHeKe9oUnkfI3EQNmblv47nm3Dbgso6LvwisBRzjc4QWzRHO7CbFG0F1wDcNqc9CAlR4qlsMsjgHZ24uztX5OHMCp5isPHAuaT8dxqJqwXPBj@hwQT4iI6Lsf@4Gopd2/fVcPsEU5r7Tc5t4mCZICkgNH5NsVLBxbxqBJRgdD@U7O5OHgO4EWRKki71Nge7CdqB9WFW2E1gsqmcOLygRUOFtibaPMeq7qDmRE39EiyKnnDhRFLWOqSNFkTzuC7Ib0coCpfCRSyxqmbgSJw4vUk5G6Sei6FNRBHHJKM1ElKIUbR@fKl2MgaIfn8mcBXoJrUqiEmCVsIAKUt8Y89FNgTYDkpkGz/FObFwsNkQFQcC6ycL9hQjekKJzMxLT9jyN4JWW4NGKb3lZpnNIC8lDqMbB0j0SAwSVCJ/Q2SyOIjKkCjbQS3gmhxoQI/K1Q1GcmKQKM8wDpES2PdyrpcRTUUssNTD4rCFC@dixxZOuEw9wll6GvxWmiARycWI5EJ51IEQhMJ7Ow6jDUJYXSyAHC1LUM9NbTMBBCUpcftOSMd4NKEqiXQWSO8TJnTOyG1ChP0dHKUl8U7YPeh33xR4lJhpOUOHDs@WFkmeNYXhGc8yEgvqf0GItPPlBE6H0EMTXo5QbQa@RzMVC6OmuZB5MrFcJuXAbcMDskE8LgRf3NsQ6tCGgvOPgMdY9RyOxYF3QBad9zjLSUuwh7UV3TZtLqCTbYkKXx83OEcDJIg@Iy07lSoqdLyNyON2NSImeM1FJlNgb3p3DPuOnC3NEqpSIhfxfVOC43DHesBfC6RxOFPuiGhHiCsr9tmoRAgflflu14MCxYr@9WgQHTIespfjT9SJREpwFuChRjBjIphSXQUHAOA41noIigiaN@AEzVk@ZQ21MqgpbpzSjKoUsEufJJdOgx5gXjLi2LFkdgXn1sDQaUW6hjzMvrFZ4TIbIfThEqsrJLoGX5vTpUJjpIAUqo4aK95iEEUBicyOYGDP3@dpNOmYozQcsNAbFo1Q73eTu3gTaoFcpqLMKZXCkUkT8zlzic7NHW0VDrNLspT3h6jJBNS54cr0WQsvSnBlf6Q6qMjGqkrmLlVCSxQsw5e6FKXcPTPkYJtGwV6G/JGfKw8ODrbtQnJ3N4qDHWxhICRwgaVs2GrFxHHxlTO7CuQTKVorW1Bl8VVkYIdKT78LxaBoHHdbeDWfjhGfXQKvbB8tzp49KW8jZZF2ZQ1FIVWqWrCySRVKbxrsCLlCVaGyrXTS7djgSSN1d0vxMCREZlxJ3w0mgVPKooxBZ1P71BfzLxoo12R444QkzDGjL0ic2Bw0ZwS1MfKtYGCEmyJLjUBGQZMTtodPCj0ar0ydN4Cn0C6Opd@bkMTf4xIxOOmSNS6xEjQuGcJFwCnqrQL7NG57dmX5qbvoDdwA6TnsuAQTfRzs@N0pNifRINZ0aWt@rL5vbn83mK663TR0Yd/9G/nAm60XIOm5Mh0btWFei978Ns8hLUAI/QJOvB3VkAZGfzSUSJ9oNYdxizqjftDzpPk2dx9DwwcdIi2uuJKVSrGbCkFkcXETXRtGZypZIEtVgrAg@Gw1wvsbnizuxcaONzOIVeBoWb5InaE3GJMhG27cMR5xkJDrMjofzFyFsFs9Ux81dlILtmMBo34qZP9/xi0JalgjBFcm3sLU8v@yxVtNN95yKbJSSIIvrmsokOablvgsUnFCrIajStKIS1B2cDF3hmrnQl0AxV@ebwO6jPd2mEEElXpSkGPBOob69jpYWM3M0CFkZFs09WDlP3Qqt3PdQtyb3Vbf@C3ByukClmFtoD6KDLd0p1KYH@XRLbnBadn/O0S2vT/f3EweeNCfBqKBveeuFQgEPwZm5Eg8nKHCW2HbzSeg82sTzg6svvNfNPEZNXoI39w48pAFAERqnJrCe4NTECPqb2KlcaM9xcFfOe59D8hN4WoyWcdrh4vbXp1T5CCUyzyqxd5hBzN87FtxRDYojHzIILMF6M4iNauilHCyTA/agRxtP1AmXpBEyGjeLXQs48VGpXksPxL2QZOfDO3zU62gbovzM6vXcLHvjer3Wksx3hyYj7O/HIxQ4CC4l5I3Hpzslssy6tHuxezUQJHYrO7@YCS/d5dZP2svkWQOcSVOwHzu2OnvjgSLX38pQMSHLGcxmhskN3N7TkaGLkmkK/W60/BgzIPte0H1joJjEp2lg6APFXqrIBRSt4s2bfHUw2lN2Icu4mENJgKj8XBjOs7uhkanzydXeu7ajQNYxWMLtcrT1m4qXcrIAPGSufDbW28jDAschaMJzE@8X46aMh0798A9at9FygJsbycYbbomNnTcWz0dgjMeWxS6H7TY0L26JrwZHjQXoSFTmdFqlgKwRBetZ34xAn1HSbV8ce4dLbU4mjpkgpF5sZJk4HK/8u@VRClqgaH7AT1w28WUOmvX@iC5XieQZmeFwAcWs3MEI5xhBkj4zK99cKbVajS0PMhlWqz0BRy7Hak9q7Cl6PHnCnsL7E3x/WCmur5f5yrmn6jV4Pgk8b9gTwEFdEF7k9hReIYzuZ8KhFBbxcr6ynC0vn1d2qmU/X689aeTzHXD97e/99G//8R/na@LlO3x5Qi/1tyGQpmn5ZfN6@eFNGd/rTxvp5WZ9edBId8pYy1Dcv/J8o2fEtolp5t/LZbrBznlTZaDRqpVKmqU/fuSus2Hk9CIn3nwQRTd6g65B0RlhqFbStfTDh@DaqaR/nFbx5A7hb4T@H8CfqSjLab6YWEvTx7WT3YOD@OVC4aWlbdQ0ccLdEIvTbMe3IVPvUsHsea7ONI01cuxdSB4u6D7ngP9ve1fb2zZyhD9bv2JNItFLpEhyco7zYh1y1xZIgfaAa4F@kAJLpimfAFniiXRiIVV/e2eemX0hxcR2kF5zh3xITEnct9nZmWdmZ2fLXTRNjhiVzvxHO2lHh@h7RKmiYQk/RYCRxD1JNNpVfonwIhughN8QDMaFHly8kNA51PGIBB6//1IOpbZkufHwqbsc63baGw@Pv3vbi@MYLSM69yyBmENrmb/fOAmCZRHpJhn1MloyNHaujbs8NlQhEyOOHyTUj4eJ5nFY4UJJHjDyFTbjZpAaw1CXUrmK8MDd32uANvRkGWtY9I6U@TWOWzM22N41cI864K5NNx8MrvSN5KbabXCDYHB7MGc8qV4t7xJ0@svlcbe8rTCpZGKoVijEI@seHHSqY7SfCW7sM9VUr/gxT@3Okp64Xy@3l0u@cROHJvL3JJ2I8m2drOXKZkXkFqTkeTrnjU9Z0TJh/tAegGHKZ2FXCe8ucBLSJWfeFcBn71omBEnrgRGO5uGY85nv1nIlRwXWc3okhc8JEeVOabDhIyR3EobiTTWkiJHyVg50MsKumbzJVKXPPswW7MFB3hqgcbAfcJm1tSQ29JTTsjFH9A3f2hsA2rqSIqwVF7JDqPKKTVB2ihBR@M3HSFhLomFrpsvVtO6uaUQpoklp5kgikUliuWYWuvGK5uTQb9SW0XB629WsUPJm6zxfaKCKThOicOSU8IZqnTQb0phyS3gbdydzKyocn2Wl9Ib4nP1gknOEWqdBKheUXuTgTY48lLi4uBSPiyvZWeSep8UikaNS0vqhlcUZ0oHwt5I35aMNkfEg4aB2gtHCxOgpVI0ExVT7ekAnPpXM6/8XB71noJkNMZL@2qwt2dgxh5udiSeSr9FxAiooE0X7COeUUvCgxJjL9HJRlMp05dC1ni@VUews6XmRTxHxGFC3QlmODbLXYTuRMFV62yBsFrz2NxK0JxJdXc97djCs1SQWy5WUISFxxsk@fzh5ZLsT9ppWMJGPl2@3PENQrqzrFrnwscyJZ1XjZ@GTLaBy7aLIiw5O8qMClRZVmvTGfClwhRokTivLwEvhQan6gIGZuUNNDhlVIa9Ml0CCPeFt@cX2dFdzyf3/st3SVJ5vONUsLT56i/mAdLQPJj@nN1aJRzeuytoV@D61QJ3F7wLnlzbXS0L@EqSuGiW8R9436vpRacoOXWe4B6SU2YRl42Y4l5Widry@9Nty6V5Tcjd8sBkcWgHSydqa2EF/PRBlTtrU1iupGVoD@3Fnc0hoCgYXmW5nR0kO9TqbM3k41p2luZ@cXR1rWBveSnk7ZkUWHBoTVo66kHtI3wvj/WuItIML5/V1sX5TfHlMD98derOYuy9xVz3hghnBYIUIs3Zfn@hxjHuvv5BZwHJgQYJATqrM8pSeGw1BHmphRn/LL39Y37QG3Uk0ibrD4@ftCHayw2FxkpNlFCcpR1Rv2EpI1fYkTawRcu9SEeGb88XFBSEOvXGBimpr7qczrXbMHvIPTtzlPajaCEI8jQJZnvdoEvGF0hrP2WZ2eTXD49/X/9zMtm9ICeHjTyuZz39wfT@TMuKbV/HLz7JGX18Q1Ih2bCd7nrjTEOEynxHySQpAgyKVVAkOLtQQIN0jgLTpxp@XBxuQIRy/@C4ceobepEmdCkLJJTZ8KjkBpzAB@HgC2Wln8h3xppowOfLZySN@EoOgCiD5B3uSJ/hWSgjUX5oRlyml9PMZ1cB4LbQmpbpmSQw6sCbXp4eylpOPU9f7fKqGTZH8cnZ1vSwWOrK9YdlxcaGuEVJc87UkOkzOIsjZ8BanfADqFX5EemWL0dllWKVdMA6ud7ygVeptGQgqTwU1wmwtgf1oyY3xw@3oQYOaKpLB/egp@GOwe/mJuRF0P7KmBidY5yRuwXRgvEzzwNyQjINOzxo36sOS8cH9IKJwNzoZy2QRzbtwjnmGOQU8hImb3N/CZv89G7nyDZPszFPJ2qUaRi0yzNv6OD/cNYMedgtCq5Y4BYXz9ZWNtlRzIjBeg7uhaQXxCfL/t8F6i@VWQn8Bqez5zBC7HJYWWgkc2oNxATkdiIFmDmcBYw3BSIgkIHIyzYAmdI6CpJWs62vEhhgl9Kb0uQqyLWJyI60Rb1TFnvLsOhix91PbojeHgPAq8dSFFaqq3bxi081g9up5DWb7WsaUIWQ3XoF6zFpjhDs2uJVQ6T6hhp9HKOlXHZ3kly9GpjIBylTaNRp17OtEhx4YDde6yxWwJ5dAuEMHhCt11ABd7GsGHatWRxNokf1zC4Y75vUlicUyFpaogZn/TqweMSDzSm4o54iTIzXXm/QFIWJCVw36R5CXpRTOx5U8IARZ@w33EjJBMDVAb@eN0Nxkph@3G7oz25dQotbw2bCNRu7QUqN0b8a94b2IQd6Kme@luWCFAsjRMWeaKuR27Qdd9xG3dGl8tS5pksjeKS3iuZNlfGT3Ni91P7Y3bBmq3rTNZzqo4Ss5Eh3Efp5@3DigLgjS4IAtagylH6mDN09pGJk9MiPuXJ/4Q@xD6@j@mvzflsY5UvI7DnAAYWDRAeMzrlUnWBECQgmxQJsP8iaR2h2Yr23FQzXARZC2xMlWgw9VVdc6hNysQEvn1qcIqB14FWu9ptZDZOLaYqYl53tnS2wdpQk7wp2XKm8H/mB1O/SbNls0d0tSorgqS@IqHM7Dh0b7Bpd1BWPUGvolQkk/SsSYrEQ4V1mXhBB/CcKrSqFl4lBfVut/kBf0Db86H9YDERavHod4D03f0/165ShfTx0U/RR9eECX60oqAdBE7q@zSR59bxr3JWiVnrcwKRx6vx8uvddM3JVVXaL0el4UXfxsKLo41D3bvM/eBtY@ko9fMvoghYzXP6YTplk6EP0LNwX9JwzK93bNCpcujKR9XkjkaNsHeeTF47yA@nrptx/ZjhOdNLu4IHV8zafxtwVVwQfxcVNdQGcplMOkuJ/CtEa6NK@ikExM7krVMtPS3i4zMMwC89fmHwOl5pqw6YCqQ3gRcrbw1tU6kQxgHATIzgHElcKuHYpZxAaRFBzzR02kcjCXfORzXckyAtM502Z1DNofDEIw1g@bWXEniOW35OR0u1lxNli@a6DCh/njBt@5eV9Idhdc1rkzLos78Gl3PDzrxBlhiyefWcdvi9O8g5bqiVzPI16ocODD5CAS0wQtt93Qma9SK9xy@3zY9w2@fK2KofPVw5eOI39SBjEdD2KSWhDjX9BSCTveUM69D/FAy3YFC7mjsEfaW5fbo3Vj21vXtpennGHY@Pe08BrN8tc1zRbv11rCMao2CP9jbUMsa2VNTyNd21PT2l/QMt9eDT/5pob/2Gq472jB1wrcommCqf8293@EuedE9cuTwcng7Ivt@7rvopCxosp@qzHRoRmOvn82ufnTYHLz/OlPv8ZFPDrq/2tDf4v41/j4JJZHeqBPT@ynd/EofsWvHe/ibf/09JQetZbXf6FaRn91dfJb21f03@g7W@/xNh71TlH83/HomB6GR0fUk8nNn59Pbk4G/C96@TXBj3B3xYGPj9WaIXulKoTcXtnlDPd17qv8MdAOb5gFrDledpCy5qdKe@gwB8/cHJ0MFKsQA0mWvXecgXAxL9yZKsWPyPNVIFuhnLiwWfY0Vk8K0QpwTbTpD5qAtlfo5TP72aR@jBJ8p830weNj3rqearI/1wGX3g8wU0K5ybxooWFOZMx/R4PvI5f@70Wk2QGjMOJf9zZVK56oVvwv)

### Explanation

Thanks to Potato44 for the idea to add machine code, it was a lot of fun to make this answer.

I didn't do CP/M COM file because it restricts the size of polyglot to about 60KB which I want to avoid.
Boot image turned out even easier to do than COM because ZEMU loads boot sector from 6th sector by default (1-based, 128 byte logical sectors),
so start of polyglot does not need to be executed. The boot code must be at offset 0x280 ((6-1)*128) in the polyglot.

I use [ZEMU](http://www.z80.info/zip/zemu.zip) emulator which is linked from [this page](http://www.z80.info/z80emu.htm#EMU_CPU_W32).
To run polyglot in ZEMU:

- Disks > A: select polyglot file
- Options > Instruction Set I8080
- Press Boot button

Function that prints one char to console (`cns$ot`) was copied from BIOS22Dv221.ASM from ZEMU distribution. 
I made two changes: character is not masked to 7 bit ASCII because we control parameters and `jrz cns$ot` is replaced with `jz cns$ot` because `jrz` (jump 
relative if zero) is Zilog Z80 instruction not present in Intel 8080.

Initial program ([Intel syntax](http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html), [assembler](http://www.z80.info/zip/as8080.zip) linked from [here](http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm#SDT_ASM_W32)):

```
    org 3120h    ; chosen so that cns$ot == 0x3131, easier to generate
                 ; this program will be generated at this offset
                 ; to run it directly specify org 0100h

    mvi c,31h    ; '1'
    call cns$ot
    mvi c,38h    ; '8'
    call cns$ot
    db 38h       ; for answer 188, NOP in I8080
    mvi c,33h    ; '3'
    call cns$ot
    hlt          ; halt processor

;;;;;;;;; copied from BIOS22Dv221.ASM
cno$sp equ 7dh
cno$sb equ 01h
cno$si equ 00h
cno$dp equ 7ch

; print char to console, receives char in c register
cns$ot:
    in cno$sp    ; in status
    xri cno$si   ; adjust polarity
    ani cno$sb   ; mask status bit
    jz cns$ot    ; repeat until ready
    mov a,c      ; get character in a
    out cno$dp   ; out character
    ret
```

This program contains chars that cannot be used directly in polyglot. Most ASCII control chars (code < 0x20) are prohibited in Simula, non-ASCII chars (code >= 0x80)
cannot appear alone because the file must be valid UTF-8. So the above program is generated by another program that is valid UTF-8.

The following program generates needed code and jumps to it.
`ld (hl),a` cannot be used because of Grass (`'w'==0x77`). `sub h` (0x94) and `xor a` (0xAF) are UTF-8 continuation bytes, they must be prepended with UTF-8
lead byte. Instruction `ret nc` (=0xD0, return if not carry) is used as UTF-8 lead byte. To make it do nothing it is preceded with `scf` instruction (set carry
flag). Also avoided `','` (0x2C) and `'.'` (0x2E) for DOBELA. `org 0100h` directive is not used because used assembler does not understand it (org is set in the GUI).
This program is position independent anyway. I like Zilog mnemonics more, so I used them for longer program.

[Zilog syntax](http://clrhome.org/table/), [assembler](http://retrospec.sgn.net/game.php?link=z80asm) linked from [here](http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm#SDT_ASM_W32):

```
  ; generate: 0E 31 CD 31 31 0E 38 CD 31 31 38 0E 33 CD 31 31 76 DB 7D EE 00 E6 01 CA 31 31 79 D3 7C C9

  ld hl,3120h

  ld a,3Fh
  scf       ; set carry flag so that ret nc does nothing
  ret nc    ; utf8 lead byte for next insn
  sub h     ; a -= h; a = 0Eh;  utf8 cont byte (opcode 0x94)
  ld c,a

  ld (hl),c ; 0Eh    ; not using ld (hl),a because it is 'w'
  inc hl

  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl

  ld a,32h
  cpl       ; a = ~a; a = 0xCD
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; CDh
  inc hl

  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),c ; 0Eh
  inc hl
  ld (hl),38h ; 38h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),d ; CDh
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),38h ; 38h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),c ; 0Eh
  inc hl
  ld (hl),33h ; 33h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),d ; CDh
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),76h ; 76h
  inc hl

  ld a,23h  ; not using ld a,24h because it has '$' (breaks SNUSP)
  inc a
  cpl       ; a = ~a; a = 0xDB
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; DBh
  inc hl

  ld (hl),7Dh ; 7Dh
  inc hl

  ld a,c    ; a = 0Eh
  cpl       ; a = F1h
  dec a
  dec a
  dec a     ; a = EEh
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; EEh
  inc hl

  scf
  ret nc
  xor a     ; a ^= a; a = 0; utf8 cont byte
  ld c,a
  ld (hl),c ; 00h
  inc hl

  ld a,4Ah
  scf
  ret nc
  sub h     ; a -= h; a = 0x19;  utf8 cont byte
  cpl       ; a = ~a; a = 0xE6
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; E6h
  inc hl

  ld a,c
  inc a
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; 01h
  inc hl

  ld a,35h
  cpl       ; a = 0xCA
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; CAh
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl
  ld (hl),h ; 31h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),79h ; 79h
  inc hl

  ld a,2Dh  ; not using ld a,2Ch because it has ','
  dec a
  cpl       ; a = 0xD3
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; D3h
  inc hl

  ld (hl),7Ch ; 7Ch
  inc hl

  ld a,36h
  cpl       ; a = 0xC9
  ld d,a
  ld (hl),d ; C9h

  ld sp,3232h  ; set up stack for generated program

  ld hl,3120h  ; not using ld l,20h because it has '.'
  jp (hl)      ; go to generated program 
               ; confusing mnemonic - actually it is jp hl, ie. PC = HL
               ; opcode 0xE9, utf8 lead byte (0xE9 = 0b11101001), must be followed by 2 cont bytes
  db 80h,80h
```

This program is assembled into:

```
! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
```

It must be at offset 0x280 in the polyglot (see line 2). Abstraction test in the test driver checks that.

### Refactorings

#### Shells

Moved shells back to longest line. I like this layout more because parens don't get aligned with other langs.
Moved Moorhenses and Flaks before shells, so they don't break when shells are changed.
Longest line has this layout now:

```
Grass  Moorhenses  Flaks  Shells  Rubies/Pythons/Perl5  PicoLisp  Prelude  Klein001
```

New shells code:

```
a=$(printf \\x00)
b=$(echo -n $a | wc -c)
case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;; 4*)echo 78;; 8*)echo 166;; *1*)echo 50;; *)echo 58;; esac
exit
```

Old shells code:

```
a=$(printf \\x00)
b=${#a}
case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;; *4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));; *1*)echo 50;; *)echo 58;; esac
exit
```

Length of `$a` is calculated by `$(echo -n $a | wc -c)` now (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592387)). 
Initially I used this to get rid of `#`, but now it is used because of shorter code.
Shells can contain `#` because Flaks are before shells.

[Yash](https://www.mankier.com/1/yash) (166) uses built-in echo command which does not support options by default, so "-n " and linefeed end up being part of the 
output, which gives additional 4 bytes. When not set `ECHO_STYLE` defaults to `SYSV` (`-n` option is not accepted).

[This TIO link](https://tio.run/##Zc3dCoIwAIbh813Fh3iQgjDBP5K6kexgmwtFUUkhle59zaUJebZ3e8bHWV8oJdiAK7q2nogURQuvgRVSgOvXMwArNcd/EQDzFyxiPoIEqHZQHUCsQb5v5McNP4ow7WLahFLsYp@6Z9kMD2TZSKlDuL7ZPtoMb7wEPOEQwXoJm9/8O8oG8F3HqDBIUyBYK06WStbSs0u6P0tNrmGo7JkgciyHDw) tests code in all shells.

Additional `(((((` before shells fix Underload and Retina. One more pair of parens is added to hide `58` from Prelude (closed with `#)` after `exit`).
`{` before `((((((` is for Japt, without it Japt hangs.

#### Flaks

Due to relocation of Flaks starting code can be simplified – only `([])` is left:

```
     line 21      (Grass(([5]{})))    scripting langs                  clear stack     Flaks main code                                                                                      begin skip code      the rest of polyglot   end skip code   print(85)
old: []{}[][][]   ((([]{})))          ((()()<<()>>)((()([])))<<()>>)   {}{}{}{}{}{}{}  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)   (<><()>){({}[()])}{           ...           }{}<>              ()
new: []{}[][][]     ([]  )                                                             ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)   (<><()>){({}[()])}{           ...           }{}<>              ()
```

[This TIO link](https://tio.run/##lY/LCoMwEEX3/YrBVbKwgmARK1m00F2/QKTEoChNVXwsJOTb08RIH3ZjZ2C4M8w9k2S0L5VidAACbcOnXc7KBtwaHD@EU0er2r1weo/gHc4RujGbwGvawcvmlUKvWHkzct9lK1gQfMDgzGnfVyzaDHM5sxbt@AaH/gs85mMe/flKlxezD37BB7hWdVWsPr8d/FjcFqwUSlIMgISM0RzYJMZCCrlUghFaGhTrNAPdG4uQxMh5SWiVIJxiKe1MV4RjCyT6BjwB) tests code in all Flaks.

#### Fission & Cardinal

Fission was moved into LNUSP: `R"12"R _*`. Second pointer is used to terminate Fission as soon as possible – on 3rd step, see [answer 54](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117635) for more info.

Cardinal was moved into LNUSP: `@  %"18"`. As in Fission, second pointer is used to terminate Cardinal as soon as possible – on 3rd step.

#### MarioLANG

Use `####...` instead of `====...` as a platform:

[image]

#### Minimal-2D

Polyglot with MarioLANG:

[image]

#### Wierd & 1L_a

Wierd: use space at line 10 column 79 to reflect IP.
1L_a, Wierd: space at line 9 column 79 is important.

[image]

#### Cubically

New code: `:1*23!/5x%6E0`

```
:1*23!/5x%6E0
! - skip over / in Klein 201
x - destroy Cardinal pointer before it hits /

pure:
:1*23/5%6E0

faceval:
0 0
1 9
2 18
3 27
4 36
5 45

program:
:1   mem = 9
*23  mem *= 18; mem *= 27
/5   mem /= 45
%6   print mem
E0   exit

9*18*27/45 == 97 (integer division)

6 in %6 is used to print mem because 0-5 are used to print faceval (eg. %3 prints 27)
0 in E0 is not an exit code, it is present just to trigger E instruction
```

#### Klein 201/100

New code: `!|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!`

After all the multiplications stack contains a single zero because popping from empty stack gives zero. This zero is added to the main number with `+` next to `@`.
Previously it was discarded with `?`, see [Klein 001 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127812).

How doors work in Klein:

[image]

#### Whirl

[Whirl](http://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/) code is basically the same, the only change is that main code assumes that current operation is ops.one (2), 
not ops.load (4).

Effectively Whirl can be thought of as having 3 operations:

- `1`  rotate one step
- `0`  switch rotation direction
- `00` execute current instruction and switch ring

Combined operations to simplify reasoning about program:

- `0000`    if current op of inactive ring is noop then just execute current op of active ring without any side effects
- `11..11`  rotate n steps
- `011..11` switch direction and rotate n steps

`0000` executes current instruction of active ring, but also executes current instruction of inactive ring as a side effect. If current instruction of inactive 
ring is harmless then we can just focus on operations on active ring without thinking what is happening with inactive ring. This is especially useful with
this program because it has clear separation: first the number 32 is created using only math ring and then we switch to ops ring and execute 2 instructions
there (print and exit).

First I wanted to have current operation on ops ring to be noop when main code starts executing. It has 2 advantages: 1) main Whirl code can be executed
standalone and 2) we can completely forget about ops ring when creating number 32 with math ring. However, it makes code longer than it was, so instead
main code assumes that current operation is ops.one (2). It means that ops.value is set to 1 as a side effect of math operations, which then is used for
printing. Old code achieved the same effect with ops.load instruction, but using ops.one more clearly expresses the intention – to set ops.value to nonzero.

```
at this point current ring is ops, dir = clockwise, cur op = ops.one
00    switch to math ring
011   rotate to math.not
0000  math.not (math.val = 1)
01111 rotate to math.store
0000  math.store (mem[0] = 1)
1     rotate to math.add
0000  math.add (math.val = 2)
01    rotate to math.store
0000  math.store (mem[0] = 2)
011   rotate to math.mult
0000  math.mult (math.val = 4)
0000  math.mult (math.val = 8)
0000  math.mult (math.val = 16)
0000  math.mult (math.val = 32)
011   rotate to math.store
00    math.store (mem[0] = 32), switch to ops ring
up to this point the program is the same as before

01111 rotate to ops.intio
0000  ops.intio - print mem[0] as number
0111  rotate to ops.exit
00    ops.exit
```

New code is shorter because old code has a couple of redundant direction switches in second part of the program, not because of new assumption.

```
old: (1111) 00011000001111000010000010000011000000000000000001100 01111110000011100
new: (11)   00011000001111000010000010000011000000000000000001100   011110000011100
```

**How to keep Whirl correct when changing something before Incident/Whirl line:**

- ensure there are even number of `0`s before main Whirl code
- ensure there are no two consecutive `0`s
- add/remove enough `1`s until Whirl works again; adding n `1`s is equivalent to removing 12-n `1`s and vice versa

I unknowingly broke first rule when added Ropy. When there are odd number of `0`s main code starts executing with incorrect direction of ops ring
which breaks exit instruction. So now there is `0` on line 3 which compensates `0` on line 1.

#### Others

**CoffeeScript**: `console.log a&&39||180` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662713))

**INTERCAL**: moved to line 37
**Brainfuck**, **Agony**: moved to other brainfuck derivatives on line 10

**xEec**: moved into 1L_a (`h#115#  o#`)

**CSL**: moved to line 80
**Trefunge**: moved to line 120
**Gaot++**, **Stones**: placed on separate lines

Comment: Nice, that is a lot of bytes to golf off.

Answer (score 17):

## 6. [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 45 bytes

```
#v<++++<;n4
#>3N.
print('1'if 1/2else'5')
#i2
```

[**Try it online**](http://smbf.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y8KysrKzw7bjQKIz4zTi4KcHJpbnQoJzEnaWYgMS8yZWxzZSc1JykKI2ky&input=)

This program prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in V, **3** in Minkolang v0.15, **4** in ><>, **5** in Python 2, and **6** in SMBF.

SMBF (aka Self-modifying Brainfuck) uses `<++++<>.`. The pointer is moved left (to the last character of the source code), and the cell is incremented four times then printed.

Answer (score 17):

## 9. Perl, 84 bytes

```perl
#v;7||"<+0+0+0+<;n4
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8
#|

#M`
print(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5)
#j␛d5ki2
```

There's a literal ESC character in the actual code between the `j` and `d`; it has been replaced with a ␛ here for visibility.

This prints [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), **2** in Vim (tested locally, but [here's](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A) a link for the very similar language V), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), [**4** in <><](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrMCswKzArPDtuNAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOAojfAoKI01gCnByaW50KE5vbmUgYW5kIDlvciAxLzJhbmQgMW9yIDUpCiMbamQ1a2ky&input=), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A), and [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@69cZm1eU6Nko20AhjbWeSZcynbGfnpcyjUx5VpcyhZABheXsm8CV0FRZl6Jhl9@XqpCYl6KgmV@kYKhvhGIaQhkmmpyKUtnpZhmZxr9/w8A).

Let's get some more exoteric languages in, via abusing arithmetic that works differently in different languages. (`None` is falsey in Python but truthy in Perl, and `and`/`or` chains work the same way in both languages.)

Apart from Python, I also had to change the vim code. Instead of making it into a series of no-ops, I just let it insert junk, then deleted the junk again at the end.

Comment: Seriously? You're going to make it extremely difficult for anyone else to create answers if you put in a literal ESC. We have to be able to test the code.

Comment: You don't have to include the literal ESC in your own answers; I just found it to be the easiest way to write this one. (Additionally, it works fine in Firefox, and in local testing; the only thing blocking me from putting it in the post is that Chromium, which I use for SE, doesn't want to put it into the input box.)

Comment: Also, you can't test locally for Vim. Languages are defined by the interpreter that is used. So it's really V that we've had all this time.

Comment: Err, isn't `vim` an interpreter for Vim? (It works in both `vim` and V, though.)

Comment: It has to be the *same* interpreter that the original answer used.

Comment: @ais523 maybe you can put ␛ to represent the 0x1B byte?

Comment: @ais523 how do I use esc literals?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre An ESC character is just a character like any other; the main problem is that it's hard to type, as pressing ESC normally doesn't work. If you can get one from somewhere (such as my try-it-online links above, or by writing a program to output the character with code 27), you should be able to copy and paste it. However, if you're doing it in a browser, this only seems to work on Firefox; Chrome can't handle it.

Comment: @ais523 thanks, that answers it because I use chrome - I didn't end up needing it for my answer but I might for languages that come before it's actually valid

Answer (score 17):

## 15. Haystack (141 bytes)

```
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L#'1r'4;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.15o|1
#|\w*
#8  ^1b0<
#|
#M`
print ((0 and'13')or(None and 9 or 1/2 and 1 or 5))
#jd5ki2
```

Note: there is an `ESC` after `o` in the third line and after `j` in the last line

This prints **1** in Python **3**, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang, **4** in <><, **5** in Python **2**, **6** in SMBF, **7** in Japt, **8** in Retina, **9** in Perl, **10** in Befunge, **11** in Befunge-**98**, **12** in Fission, **13** in Ruby, **14** in turtlèd, and **15** in Haystack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#HcdBDoIwEADA@36By@IeWjDRbqFRU2J8gPICA2rwgCatNgYv/TsKmdOMNFjdKLuJcVEt1azKUy1SFkcSHERpXQk0KGrfB6B9Ua/Y@CQyUDx/c6AtYsM3Vf0PdLrAK/Tug1IqvLpOcCEyH2Tt3X067tAH5LWew1NMlgE9ks48ez2OPw)

#### Explanation

```
#v                           go down
 v
 >                           go right
  3N.                        does nothing important
     15o|                    outputs 15 and ends program
                             there is an <ESC> after 'o' since 'o' in Vim enters insert mode
         1                   I added this to satisfy Retina
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for checking out Haystack! :)

Comment: @Kade It's a nice 2D language, an online interpreter would be more helpful (although I have already downloaded the Python interpreter) :)

Comment: @Kade There is a TIO link for haystack now!

Comment: @MistahFiggins The link works for me and outputs 15

Comment: @MistahFiggins Cache? Because it works for me without any problems or any error messages

Comment: How do you go about getting a language to be supported by TIO?

Comment: @MistahFiggins I asked Dennis in the tryitonline chatroom

Answer (score 16):

## 13. Ruby (129 bytes)

```rb
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8  ^1b0<
#|
#M`
print ((0 and'13')or(None and 9 or 1/2 and 1 or 5))
#jd5ki2
```

Please note the literal <kbd>Esc</kbd> character on the last line between the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>, as per [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62131/ais523)'s Perl answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#M2DmR)

This prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang, **4** in <><, **5** in Python 2, **6** in SMBF, **7** in Japt, **8** in Retina, **9** in Perl, **10** in Befunge, **11** in Befunge-98, **12** in Fission and **13** in Ruby.

Just a minor modification to the existing `print` statement to abuse the fact that `0` is truthy in Ruby. I had to add some spaces to the other statements to make it parse correctly.

Answer (score 16):

## 16. Pyth (159 bytes)

```
#v\;2^0\;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L#'1r'4;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.15o|1
#|\w*
#8  ^<1b0 <
#|
#M`
print ((0 and'13')or(None and 9 or 1/2 and 1 or 5))
#"07|5//00;16 "jd5ki2
```

**Note:** there is an `ESC` byte (`0x1B`) after the `o` in the third line and after the `j` in the last line.

This was quite a fun experience. Japt and Pyth are both golfy languages, but Japt is infix and Pyth is prefix, and Pyth auto-requests input and fails if arguments are missing.

Before the Haystack answer I had an almost-working solution using `#`, which gets a char code in Japt and loop-until-error in Pyth. Pyth happens to be very useful in polyglots, since the common comment char `#` essentially works as an error silencer.

When I got home I managed to find a this piece of code that worked in both using `//`, which works as a comment in Japt and two divisions in Pyth. Then it was just a matter of getting the Befunges to route correctly.

This is very unlikely to be optimal, but it's good enough for now. I tried to test them all, but I'd highly appreciate someone double checking that the outputs match.

Prints [1 in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [2 in V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [3 in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [4 in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [5 in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [6 in Self-Modifying Brainfuck](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [7 in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZcOzJeMFw7N3x8IjwrMCswKzArPCohMichMSdMIycxcic0O240CiN2MCNfcUAKIz4zTi4xNW8bfDEKI3xcdyoKIzggIF48MWIwIDwKI3wKI01gCnByaW50ICgoMCBhbmQnMTMnKW9yKE5vbmUgYW5kIDkgb3IgMS8yIGFuZCAxIG9yIDUpKQojIjA3fDUvLzAwOzE2ICJqG2Q1a2ky&input=), [8 in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [9 in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [10 in Befunge(-93)](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [11 in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [12 in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [13 in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [14 in Turtléd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf), [15 in Haystack](https://tio.run/#IJnm9), and

**[16 in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#HchNDoIwEEDhfa/AZmAWBUykU6ho2hgPoJyA4E9wgSatNgY3vTsKeavvTTi2Wnai1XUIiVmJJZPHksfEj8jJ80rbiuEo8Pw@MNyXzZqUiwIxDO03Z7gF6AzdBJj/YXi6sJcf7AfSVMDV9pxKnjmfNs7eZ8MOnAcq5AKaobKMYSLqoIpCCE0bSB5Rr56DnKYf)**.

#### Explanation

What Pyth sees here is:

```
#v\;2^0\;7||"string
multiline
string"07|5//00;16 "string
```

This translates to the following pseudocode:

```
while no errors occur:
    evaluate ";"
    print 2
    print 0 to the power ";"
    print 7
    print "string\nmultiline\nstring" or 0 or 7
    print 5 or 0 divided by 0 divided by (missing)
print 16
do nothing with "string"
```

The first loop exits on trying to evaluate `;` which isn't a valid expression. Then Pyth just prints `16`.

Comment: Extending in what way? I still need another 5 or so bytes available for my answer ;)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre By adding the rest of the details to the post. I just wanted to remain sane and thus posted my code before anyone stole my place. :D

Answer (score 16):

## 67. C11, 1674 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>.+?+++++::@
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#
#x4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#( prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm 
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005565 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1749 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTrLcttIkufGL/SlDLINgCRepCRLAklJtqVZd9strSU/wiQtF8EiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzE/0ptZBb5ESu6O2I1YSAIKqKzMrHxVVpa6NB3@/nsBL3IW@TcDP8pIxtKM9BLvmiUGeXpDDqmXbldrksShkqg3cr1wQLIhI14YjzLS93yWSi7NSJPEORYDG6RAEkZ7AkzqRwnBISS48olH3DgmXZ8ODZf4HodNowD7M5bECYN7SkLGeiSNmev1PZfTIWySsTD1ojA1iOdekbHn@6THfBiwIO5WABkZpUufBClD6kUSgcuN77A6fysygAnZbLospgmfbkRiPvfZrMcJjWNgUiqQc2A88wKWEi9TUsJo6qEMYUjKwh6XVDyXbkRouDxLcu1RQoHfUcJxpyzJYHoGx0uGLGGAkiLxQUIDoo4TLwMRoCCPyBmjCblIGNOACiiApS6NgY8VkkAsQgoZTsTgiqrXlePTEwUUJkYYNM6kQlK7@NefJUqMBileOvDXkGVHOv71ObkttrENXAAyUGqcqFQjjW8kNdttBn8Tu2sOkqkEWCWQik/MKM5MwEyTDNhbtPTrqhH7S2RJ/Y4mloxIQPVAF@RFSN5W@LzcUZIw4GIhUnoFU/ajcADShKkmoxClEZIdCxTgRmEvrRB2DTKLQqGhaMzlezH0QGUpKoR2QTzURckLB@DiBBcAy8vlOaObRv6Iw8HINEPzA5nAUMT4ok/ekj71fBwC/YhKcJ2wdORnOGYU9lDvgReynkFmbLhRD4GC6BrIUUDKP4DPBEuexpkCYFBDxKeKXf/86996gwHgOXLdKOnlxvqW9CJ3FADDlDNLwRDRXKOQ@pwtgKsgdTEcCFxT3@vRDMmHNzkJzgSnOo5Gfo9EQDAZe@BYQ3oNztjvMzdjwsSjUQY8VkhAr0R88ITdwsQD2gXFcgKcNp@2Tg6fgZZcJgxGD0ZZf5fo8TFRUvOjerCvHjxqM@BNM7RS0TQHDlibUeKf4E15yHDeHi30idZz4UXoRX48HEHMgJ4wjSGaJChMl8J0UgwqGcS8CulyQfNIBIbOXXTMlISRLvj1bGLcRoQN4Hgd/TbHsNDpDG7VxFhvycLAOsHIsnQtSPjRGAhz3jBwgk2HSJwOKJDK8gkdiQkJivzL6tSuQrB0xNZlZFfveqAdtAMINbkyluYI4LWqgAFsQntLThHQG8DiihC90CTx@qDkAOw2uSEuQ2cAr2AiziGRETeM1AM7ivrE0qvb299RfpaYR/oHk@pfzAd1jJO/o@Yj0mdj4tNwMKIDMOQohCHUdVmc5R4EM0kz8JG7YZB/1POYbqRDqXh4lzaPbXm0X6KB0UdoL4/QFM0eBBWAqHUfvJzQZMA9kfS8BPzFv7lLHQCu7xCXPyHICgOf5HtYmC1MYGRswtxRBu4Ghjweeu4QbBe5C4XDiuh4lzx8WqYOIUfvz0kjM3bzcVUyzPknZONeFDpqdB0PRH1E1Vz5wJW//OFhzDQNNiCO5ixChFr6apjUANvLhQar@TlmEhD@Zks396x5ejGXJwj4Z1yYEvbbCBQG9uwNQgSh4XzZX4qMXhoqsFR4qQdSxwUcbf3ixSmuB@@YyGFA7mItWw7mEWQ0MDxfoLFjpgSJucOI6CFRch5Uma@nn4EtM01c3tCXkghZM0BOKsqLd80QfRZ52d0FlTTX4ThJpUJastypwBrmp2BC4cj34WUUchdTmXYLtuayNDXAYUC2BmYjwJ1cZtp0FTAbJtGYsKnmKJvI/UmFPBt1vcn/Q424yJe4w6yW1MA//RE9rAHOFCHLuejWIITwLoC9l5D0kJcerkV9SJEWqTPPtieYJLYlOb7JhlFYW40m8qKnKrK1t2YAi4sR32xeR@VlVHzAKy@8ilBLZjBrXVqGvb2CArL99ZF9Lx3y2wroGlvrPXx0GnT7/LYBIEQruGNsvCOIwkgQBwl5ITVf84cBEXMTB6uBaYX8UwZ2PmD6Xs3seqHZZf37IE@ePn3BYfrdrncfEIgB9zOz5wawZNTdJCXIR4ZrCxdZkfPFKMl8vWdm@GT//W89kPe6Nob0JoUM9mreuAzZGDWj9@9VTj4UX/htsyI/j3zY3XwHh0sxa6X@vLEZ1z55zcDaIb8I@aYGOPV98CEQGfj2ujmDJ/ijHps9NyPlMlxd/8To0At0sOUdw@IKhFdc0zGzug/LnUVcoMFkP/Ej2jPF9stjC40K2bMJHUThjbkUzY2k@wdYna2zZLHfyoajbCTuuMn6nu68GP8ecsEc0to@emof54974IGJnftsV7hNAtFFP/HpldnF5mUfmpunKiaTeAPY0c2e94G9O4@py8xxio@NZvMKsiMf9snnv745P3vQfjhCSJsSX9w3onsRurCehNn3McEsfX77M4bH7cClPlhfTdgeljn0JTF5dwTr0@4N7suHf96GkOqgXCZ6tNh8LKoocXz/INclOsSehru3t3m0KLhwBG4E@0T2veUH1hAvgHlXe0vNe43Di/TFXicVFtXHzd2GIESvKdFdn6ZgI1kuZnYNauG3h2wWlwoXjWfReshi7zA122/et2VZjIw9N4JlPOb6xhcfXu5b3e7mAws0WEjjt8VQfMsN9zmjPVxzvz1ouZGb4U7hHtv5A2FJJOm4DVqyCyO6T2huNMa/e9f6YXTNxH3zcvRlI1d/IOzoPjcJSDTXh/fc71nrOy@FoAO3zeHwaiNXmetv/I4xKkpgl5aSqmE9qJ6NxnxuvDBeGqfGOTn3/Ch9UB6wR01Tcd9sygvQbuLRUHfRhpfbm4dtZIwvbeSI3@9RMPUHkb@zOzAp3DbK5nyU9DG2PySWh2OUbX8vRomU@jWvHM638mklL3jCNy/JC1zpvIZcgJUgYXxjP9uqkAKWG0YBBIosSgzC4VSVlsuaJolBaHKDEMBmULyOh6UUUSJMCfh@xmG9Pmm1SPF2sm/t21PSIPK@TDodgZVv6o8nMS/AvRZDW0XaaRSV9@@VotIO94mlcFAGe7nNoHQFru/xh@BzMXUS0oBXb7A9m6kjSkTgmFgXHNKwB5nRm9DjuzA3SkShQ1TTeBb6j7/38nLpgMEkAy@lPggCC/xRwIbR@EDQzakfxTHFcivigLXYF/s0/dkRScde5g5FlRTixpuTi928xJUfNsDLGaZES1wIpUJXH3igmVCa4KYXMWFXOeH5qNmkIBiPgpCMvV42TA3wsNBlvIQ2K@sAJwmChVkSoV1WyAvSY5gk8G3m5xHo1o@iK767RU7@8XdR2INOD00I2zPyvNK8RJGAM9q8mua60Qi4niH5wpIoB1FRyLCkjEAiN@AVTHzXiDukvOIIlqjP6m1IRtTcnh2dE/2YKHhOguU3x@urxaPXf3nbsjqNbyQwYcNg4o6fy03@SX9ip3KFzECcKdrVcrcF3YtehcjFiZxPC2vyvAQ9NyrhTUTFNlfXrH4W8HI@tzs25vUzXiQNccXEOjls59MMXjWOWjhNo6jCTiOAnbt@npFtPExiIBJoiQMAgsczWAvCIcUJ@UqGaCu6S@xtC96EQHwsPwaNxf5ueUttPmfdEU9Er6tGtdbg0yleNupN3kpYL8ICdetje9wx05lU2u3JT1Z1AmKLEgB/bKLnHP/6/LZoNK2vX1N6A/v8qeLwTT@6d/H27MXZ8fnF0cWbcxDjVMyycBIlAV2ECDSC2IegOIx8XvEHeSQeS78fNuahIxec/P69XBTtPAaQPFCRM66rXC1KuhykKjP14dTBo0YQFWekQe23G4INZ0YmDWDnPbCzysz8LUeiqqRISZ3YFtG01V4OL8R1ABcBkS2xP7t4yFtAbQbCuQrgnG8BI5jcOInp/xLnZ0fn59/nHKG@xzkAS9@jvkT45OjFy3XCSzQRYK0/XxjgsTgaPZ5AGgvxq88tEwvwM4uJ8gOUmUNDvB6Kqh71FyEpnRfo0Ib6GFB98Ek0Zr6VS9EpCfq/QY78FAJgrwce3b3JMCBAJBQ1uXlhTi7A1I35@lQhsoSwaWO9kA4OP4bUwP0kBhc5HMecbjqLajPzn3/9mzh/amfQ/ve83Yf2f4r2RxMFtH5gIXiciwbF8vbFGUlhlRETD@hkaU4Y6HEh8cIR5DsBSPCaCwTBBbOL@S7wqK23IE9QAggTIxYGKU6PJR11mGXxvmniugyJVt/gBR42AT1AjDPcKDB/G@FxIMRVc2d7Z8s2gUn9eoaQV5kHWG0QCDVtH@xHuvbixqeuS@r1OpFT2K6yxo4jBGkW6cea/GnOaBFgJbGEtwiMgSGLEdDXzIepRVq2NRyK/qfYCuk4sDoLvUCAV3kDQDT8HObykGEFiXJRYcGaTTIeDG9mqQnkBWFEApQTPxSeIdIBkcCtydKa7QK/0MNLCt5KTmgsq0F@h2C8ALEvbzIdAhbyXxssJ4T2f4h2q23p3zqbDjTntnO0fm6p3j11xLmQw/MwwirTCfBK1KpZrZn2jrbkJ3KOCrhFr/gKKMEPwK9c5n2O4vTo2fGLn0/PztfO3TikchdMIUqzXm7rRqXVmTeUOzY/E@nTE/P81dOTmSCXucq77nK1Cfldxu4h9k6Ub9ZJ8Y41Qrb1RxEvtpMbJ7LYbC4BPhP7zDWqqnY7bXXqzXZYWCP/ddOheMEo4Tk4tNopPxJXyIYAMy9QXURXYB4PnPbpGUJ4X5bP/bx8NB6qVZtmj12beAokGeasB9ZGtb7CrSZOJoUMZuQhTuRfirYMdBe0XGmtaLDMiNi4RXNOVkauT3e2zICf5sVUcH385xI8NoK0zANODn9hYchuiApRLKAQHOgI9vKJVpn9d1Nlfh69pM1/yWuzd337WLn1I4hgRdPhCaAzBTf@1CbtrN1vh@jLzo35o2mYzq1a9Bs3JoRfrakWhw27XCuVy8WwpBZDDECPH2PeOC1CfLs0ZEOeAJBe9DUHVlWIh41i6BRpXS32GtUSHwGvsJe8hQHfUtO4LdKpWXwM4aQCXxKGUZupxVTD/NAyDHsK/H2OvLBoVgIa36oykSd4rI/ki165jDwYxUtk4JvZPi9z42qfmzxTdfJlzRwEDo/@yqqN/v57wd4hRFanUfmgWnt0qOmqbJql9vNrR2nRftX4rXN2dXb2Xik8O9Vke0t2wi2pYJasr09M89OnTxDpCWnpynWn9UhtPnlSqjg7u6XKoaPYlUPb@uEH29bUalU7/@EH1SZnirJdU84/Kr9JheYPoNzazqPDHz5JBalw2SzDZTSN8gE2yvv7h1LhUx366p3plJTrrbrRbOqdZksq3EqFL1Mc1JjUX3Po1nM@HK7tvclLeNT1Tis@e3l8dH5cqdb1QvX5aaV6/uZpwYaX7fkbdtXg7fXx0fPTNxeVqhjylxdvj9@cnRw98zwvTnu9tBcNO83Dw7Kh6/qh0ey0kPpk63TnFLic/FRulhtZlpEPlyUw2efNyRtTrwMXL6XCaz5Gb2sw6qtUaBVa6kH1oGr51rU1sa/sq1fR6eL39BQ6vIn1OUqsoTW0e7ZtTyz2xrqZWDdWEJ3aPXgy@LECaHpWf2INrNAKbXsFz/2/wWn06jQCVBEMyyZWhlitPjwHp6evAFkfCH@GH8@yLOBvYl3Dr@Xb/Pp4aVmaBHl2Z3snru781sJqCtne67TYxMs6Mqko7Rau@gUzbbdNYXNyFcwG@6fTy8vnRxdHl5cmyq9QmNSL5cOyfghXo1mu54@DQq@JUgNRSooK@XDcVhzaoA7fcRfxkKZld8rFW7o/mmLMKNkljbv7tuU4pSOSv2zBS97cdRyWUpdz4SiCLVVl19RXZbs9qfarsoap3B44nV0DJ7DwbUv7aNfr6s621mzuVLUokZWJHCUKuZ2KH/V2Wlf5peGPpuHH/N7UbtU6gACMxl8FPECN3717h3/vxtdj0eIN8e3dvHP5BS9IpMmQEqUwLah8E062tjVIhJi2taPulvfyn8YjDfiRlZqGP7IizWTesAvIv1QwnNeyXYUe0ICDm/HIZ4YP6UZtT5LhkhpdNvBCqd68DXtSIU0ZXMEZZSPGxqPRmM2vZ166Tz9/pjGsaaZjYDivVvd2t3f3atXdyu7e7ta2vbO9XbGrFfvJ7pM9q2Jb9q69s7u9Z1d2t/ZqW1tbe9C7vffELEmFHutjrWC0S@TabtuS519iksLaEfWVWNHtg9GuvPMENsS1JwABKwweDdbxEDUyhk0JD8CJSrRbNE0QlOZMAbcoWuzYUmEq9bAwv7XnYCCZ1ptSUcExSk0q6LVoKyoUi0WIOhdNuSafGqnUYCAFEEtBxsGFdPI12ra/hT87hf1YqW0ptXajIAzKfqIVmtUnRkpvCh3xjahb8LFT4GZYtQtk4v1f/cIupD9esqRV69rQWFxzM1szuqXWhvfxdYD/CZam6e6PvcHAq/746SvkNERRqtuE2DtoFt/0uvitw@39s1MhKnlnW9YK6cfLj5dVMJm9vZ3C7zDwgQwIeuepQJ/BKjkKNuUCR4n3iuKWM5znA9B4NYLUY24sBK3F97poLivfhAUtf@L/bwvfJOQLzUTFBoQgt8L3waTEw1FHI7ez6omKvbiB1@b7/YRloyQkliPqMojCc@ZNoILmTRoIwDfpEIVUr2E7xKsjMnhCxpBTwGs2otzAps9ClXPhdTRHWi5kcE6aMHqJl6Xx5bIAnwq2xHzcoCemLfrmr8BegOVaV81Ha3cAWlYHYJS2peTT/CPTgLxWnWOokD89jTvjITnSZnPiLCw68@8LVUylUlYJHAmnXYod6RfV1W4xaXO@BY8fux/jVtBxtKCR4bNcDpypdKV6AqSUNYKGbjsxMOtkrXLZ6zQC7Rc15swHDQuAgTZiTrXbuabDRq6uVKt8aYX6t7BTOWmFZbtTGVVKHxpfKrRhVSbwB2Kr@JXfQHgzUapZ40s5dGgd/jB/XJFE3EjL1FmtL8GQK9VvfGnRTsPSHB8GlssnMBngM2355XJHA@I@dK4PdPzHj2nZb04cX9c1hPpYOzhpZdDolBv4vq/S@uTgS2sE4/dVeDaAjK8B8zBuVQeAD/hzQMZCfQvWBY8TZG8C7AWNRunDQelDqfHo0ZfWRA86FSH@fWuheGR@gswv24ha@rBsWFwkvHyryj95@z8ZpZTIFbA@EHIlXhopOCx9gJ544Q3T/wE)

### Numbers

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 6 languages have to be tested manually:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Modular SNUSP (#31) [online](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident (#33) [local](http://nethack4.org/esolangs/calesyta-2016.tar.gz).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Surface (#66) [local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).

### Explanation

#### Adding C11

I am using the trick with utf-8 literals (introduced in C11).

```c
#define u8 "C99\0"
puts(u8"C11");
```

This trick can also be used to distinguish C++11 from C++03.

Cubix and Retina broke as a result.

#### Cubix

Cube size 16 -> 17. Moved `4O6O@` further in file, it ended up on line 13 (`#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.`), which broke fission, cardinal and minimal-2d.
So I placed `4O6O@` on a separate line instead and padded it with `#x`.

#### Retina

I ended up adding 2 lines (`#define u8 "38\0"` and `#x4O6O@`), so total line count remained odd, which is good for retina.
But retina still didn't work. So I moved empty line around to fix it (line 20 in answer 66). This empty line ended up before `#x4O6O@`.
Thutu broke, so I added `#` to that line.

#### Surface

Surface still prints NULL character before 66, I didn't fix it. (It is fixed in the next answer.)

Comment: Given that #38’s C has so far been tested with `bash run-wrapper.sh gcc -o polyglot polyglot.blah.c`, I would prefer to define #38 as the C11 answer, and #67 as the C99 answer, but that is trivial. Nice Addition!

Comment: I thought surface printed a null character, but when I run it on my machine I don't seem to get it in my output.  How are you running surface?

Comment: @WheatWizard I run surface.exe on my Windows 7 32-bit machine. In console window I see blank space before 66 (NULL char is displayed exactly like a space char). If I redirect output to a file I can see it in hex viewer: ...0D 0D 0A **00** 36 36 │ 0D 0D 0A 0D 0D... (newlines and other text are added by interpreter).  Also, python program `print("\x00\x01")` produces exactly the same output (minus newlines and interpreter text) as surface program `.+.@` - a blank space followed by a smiley face (char \1).

Comment: @stasoid Hm, I'll investigate perhaps it is a difference between running on windows and using Wine.  I may have also made a mistake.  I did run it through a hex editor but I might have missed it.

Answer (score 15):

## 7. Japt (50 bytes)

```
#v;7||"<++++<;n4
#>3N.
print('1'if 1/2else'5')
#i2
```

Man, it was fun to fit Japt in there. Hopefully it didn't kill anyone's plans...

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrKysrPDtuNAojPjNOLgpwcmludCgnMSdpZiAxLzJlbHNlJzUnKQojaTI=&input=)

This program prints [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/#xOPSv), [**2** in V](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrKysrPDtuNAojPjNOLgpwcmludCgnMSdpZiAxLzJlbHNlJzUnKQojaTI&input=), [**3** in Minkolang v0.15](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%23v%3B7%7C%7C%22%3C%2B%2B%2B%2B%3C%3Bn4%0A%23%3E3N%2E%0Aprint%28%271%27if%201%2F2else%275%27%29%0A%23i2), [**4** in ><>](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrKysrPDtuNAojPjNOLgpwcmludCgnMSdpZiAxLzJlbHNlJzUnKQojaTI&input=), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/#8H7LV), [**6** in SMBF](http://smbf.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrKysrPDtuNAojPjNOLgpwcmludCgnMSdpZiAxLzJlbHNlJzUnKQojaTI&input=) and [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrKysrPDtuNAojPjNOLgpwcmludCgnMSdpZiAxLzJlbHNlJzUnKQojaTI=&input=)

How this works: `#v;` takes the char code of `v`, or 118. Then `7||` returns the logical OR of 7 and the rest of the code, which is wrapped in a string with `"` to avoid any syntax errors. The result, `7`, is automatically sent to STDOUT.

For future polyglotters, `"` can be changed to `` ` `` at no penalty to the Japt program (though I'm not sure about the others).

Comment: More on Japt is in [answer 58](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118064).

Answer (score 15):

## 14. Turtlèd (135 bytes)

```
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L#'1r'4;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8  ^1b0<
#|
#M`
print ((0 and'13')or(None and 9 or 1/2 and 1 or 5))
#jd5ki2
```

This prints 1 in Python 3, 2 in Vim, 3 in Minkolang, 4 in <><, 5 in Python 2, 6 in SMBF, 7 in Japt, 8 in Retina, 9 in Perl, 10 in Befunge, 11 in Befunge-98, 12 in Fission, 13 in Ruby and 14 in Turtlèd.

First line added #'1r'4 near the end of line, Turtled takes #[string]# as string input then 'X places the value of x on the grid, r moves right 1 space on the grid. The value on the grid is printed at the end of the program implicitly.

[Try it Online](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzwqITInITEnTCMnMXInNDtuNAojdjAjX3FACiM-M04uCiN8XHcqCiM4ICBeMWIwPAojfAojTWAKcHJpbnQgKCgwIGFuZCcxMycpb3IoTm9uZSBhbmQgOSBvciAxLzIgYW5kIDEgb3IgNSkpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)

[Link to Turtled docs](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/turtl-d/)

Comment: @Sp3000 - edited and fixed (should be)

Comment: @L3viathan - [This link should work - it contains the missing ESC literal from the last line](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7Ml4wOzd8fCI8KzArMCswKzwqITInITEnTCMnMXInNDtuNAojdjAjX3FACiM-M04uCiN8XHcqCiM4ICBeMWIwPAojfAojTWAKcHJpbnQgKCgwIGFuZCcxMycpb3IoTm9uZSBhbmQgOSBvciAxLzIgYW5kIDEgb3IgNSkpCiNqG2Q1a2ky&input=)

Comment: hooray! My language is used. Also it has a capital t, unlike brainfuck

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon It's a fun little language for some challenges :) I saw you post a while back and thought I'd pick it up just in case.

Answer (score 15):

## 300. [↑110010000100110110010](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%E2%86%91110010000100110110010), 14244 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::   _@_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~* __+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@)++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:peseps>Ex Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:F 4, ._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8ogr ca34* 16  prstd   
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4@ZbnRyQLvA2AQBVQhQfxINDNZpP3Ure72SLZt68EotEFoABUE6hCVwEk0Gx2SJpdrTX2zno0skOWPb6SZjwrrydivBM7a3nHnomwv0445pN/QPuxseHYsP6B9pyTWYUCCIDdsh2xsbEggcrKx8mTJ0@ePCefTcPr/fznEfywJ05/2u07IzYyvRFru9aF6ars/pTdMywvp2ckCWPtut3xwLRHXkmKMI0xb2S4I9Y37O7Y6JosAr46m713rP7IdJPMM03WNPvOJYRnGLPNS3Zot6w2QGIj59y0rdemC2FZxh6Y/TeDNyPWcgYDw257bOha9ohCc4w9MeClM26dM6PpjVyjNbIcG4LyjD21@8ag2TYYRR@6Jk@0zQBU65zSzIcUGHvkuJ4JOTgt0/Mc9CyCp@FazsPdx58sxNfS7BMDkBr2zclC9prGnlmm215MobPPTw8OFn0z7DPFsdnBTZS0LNsdj5zD0SL8HNvtmrbBdLWo6ouBeSDmyOwX0oX0XBCEHVgu1KYhaq00qxl7PGiaLhBfVOGlNeqpkODU4QRnjt2fMnMCwADHDkQzR8zC2mK5dBpjwv@J2XLs9gw8eJkAB@Cag@FoyhRmO4IHIMhxmTc0WqbSNvvWwBqZbda3ADunI7DxGFQ4Ozenl44LFa9wViREvKHZsjoWJhEl8CRktgdmc9xlzng0HAN6HmtbntHsQ7TmlLXNjjHuj5KsCWFAPPK/7Jm2QMmyu1iOZzMfhGBDE@DYb2pAG6vfZ4DOOaKDWXtsBwMu0R@jNk3C0mwjqP0ZuQCS0ff80s9nPJcNpnviOl3XGACjtk2iweeHT5jXclx4gy/G5a1gHZiWMWI7Oyy6//hBlFUDMqpuUwpIWmFXjLGIH8gujP7Y9NjAmELe9ggaF3Oo/vwUEkRn0Y1oiUUzGaanWTbLstDYCkzPpRk0iSI4oNXqGQ2@eaYXWFYDvs9Fk5hPxzW6Vt/kULpOv4OAtpFj9RzT4TedjSZ5aIvy2GaZAstvs@0c24bfIivqkAlCzDKtmINvHr4AoQgYaPDNZHlOAVsgO0ER2B7rGAOrP@XQh0ME32I5jW0DREBTA8h6ASAUdYQw/wnDG/WAsD3jAkAqfescxYUZSAysrRQ8UltbKRJZKBt5ll7P7PcxVyAUkChXYNuQax4KnYWcgY56QfcL3@1R8Qmv7TR8AcdtKHEByJsGSqWRVNvwhXcQQzrIGx2Eiw7yQtfAXwd3BqFCvDyE5aGu8gFp9TbRFqQrpNWQmChQNKQBJGNQdZksg8rLQvVmsHpzGQZ4AgLbeQYypaCxQpYVthmQq5hmQHoNkMG610CWaYCEhsCgSjWoUw0Q0YBZNACqZXJMCtFVy2A4pM1AWiCBloU0WXBDvWh5/EI6qHgNstQgT10vzlgLcNNzUMhchnhOz0PlbUMYEEsHXHXgFh2w1QsQjmkLQLgCsuS2TwijP@wZSAuoAWRkYDUgSA5wItgQH9z6doazFMVumiOrJV1L0Kp4DxiWOL70QAkA0oQZDDtQYMAZ98QCCRgHgTQvrMae2QcuAhnSMsCNbAutHSWHD8caqShnoZsynQvsSKn5z2XjkYhoutiLgrxqm67LMC50tl6ShIk3bnrmqzH2tTO8OiCdTBCsHcPqBwhQ0zFG1A/AM@pBftN5tDuuM6D2NUBh0Xec4QqxC6LpEgF96lyaM9RnkssYDvsgz8HfBEKMjT4gc2mQPkDqQjhXjhAkwnStngUAKSuQq5Zrtoj2ouiQOgMSeB7FEtOrdzII5X6oW8iwoQNC1cM09rjfL0F3Z7ZYpppqmxcp9OFdx3yXgTj4nQn0hwJE04C@nDpTxCKAdEdXqZs69WvWcwbzRePi5TAoes/CLqB/aUyh9jogWcyJMQCNg2G3bkPHPQCO4TWINeHxjueQtR07OgqgXLrQvUKhg5IAyD7RZGQNTNDHHEiCNZ4lpFG4EWbNKbAyUSurkjrGMVkglCotEop7ZEMevLFAx9Yet5BqmLdlEwdBh@BRb1UFuFzpVNEBTc41jTaPhtoFYhTSj6C3M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbA23HU5mFaiEwfNfpAI9RFw2qBiSd5dOismPJA6@J2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4Z@IN@AmgdpAvQxzovLfYaAvs9j/VbY9edsskQKsAaQKxRy@l0gGlfm8MegGCDNmtNW9AqoZTINFLbIQnUGi4UOXjbNCGObUKx9558jXVNoDb0yB3AlDh9VoDhkIpApDBs3lvbBlAKi9AaToksACZI0XEcFf3bjukRj4A2E7R4zMwzu9QioHl1ZjJogNoHMCdoBDawLAgc0aoQPmYoLS0MZiUq/xPThhbTAmaEtg7Vh/roLuuA7h/qrFG5M1otczgS7OGQFLPskEJzdIAKDfkqApjq9aTNe6CLzWEgQVTJ55xQD26ck3BFRZ/0LANFrDAwoE@3zUCFZVyg9Kc3socYFwu5yy8wzhwGL@QVOAypJaB2R7JhPEIJgkLRavVQBI5QyJCWAY3MHd8sPviFs3cHTOkEeSM2GkgbSU0FXojHahgKfPs3AanDPsKqznlg1DmPW0Ab3mAJZCdAst8O@6opQwVZeBvQgWM7S6ACMQO4GGU@hOqCmPEEpYbRD5iRmos3V0cop2e2L/Zf0HUOh44LLYMLnSlKMl5lIe5yuJ0SC7qIONjN8z0q9BRR7OdHI25zDftgB1ETw5YK@qQBkgKEGLcAQOY5PMcQwtTqCZbA75IkPmcm6EJt20SV1HCnHAgUD3plyGjKLNcFMXiBfQPvevw@RCU@ha7AaLdRsiI5qN0vZq4iR@@Nm9Zk0cxooaf60pMuDJd10MJwQdeARhSLdrxovEz@lDIUJKec4ShFSfmvDBEpkgpVHuuA0QIdwQEImpOp3YrJc01MTjJ5POoU5Dg4MCFXzdhXjOFoEbuX4IdMMziHdk1vZdaFXltR4FdBP8IEA1IqBhguqBfQCEHLLhbbTYO9AenhMmWyR6lRLaSnpmaDvEy7HeQlCIG4hMur8iw8t0UOJdSrYQkwOpWcOok5Ar4nJSihDB6plOg/0YOUPB5G6gz3HNs0PMBiXAOJs6tARYcOIEbIWKBzWC1r1BBayp07vr6yUakAs4ESBWKzHQ8r9/44igqSGiKrpISITNSRczLCthGLQ3kx8jXHBrQl4NRKlV2Nei60OHq/liASkFWykZN9wop6fmydj9uLFW2jJ0aSsdWBrmS1RnJZgs6ft4bKOqpG56gKyn8UqYrMi@kJ9A3mJV@sUFlEc00Ptd6KQCVUwzHEQPDqUhLxpMJvxtB701ZfqATcBY2dS6MmoH8uLPVAECWFTuA32hstlQPB5sDhsCe7p59WRFvkgammZZfmPPpOy@iT9yZGl/20Dw/vH@8ef62xBEbfapYWPVJWtpDHrnY8Ubr2OJVV9dJmGMYM8IPGetiYcD6OLIlgpjiTkKo0bUHnMvHJeXT82SJJQBNCclAO4MbvgkrD44DSJTUNr7fQCbNuIgFZBkn8uEw5ZD7MwIGoY7jh4/Nk/Po1Vt4iUkPhj5j1xwYH4HumDm0/nYqBCwqYH9Ts8B6R0oIWatk4/jlzhWP6@HyCWvMiMqRKh1jmk6OD/eMKge0Z3rnZ7ysUJeWNQJcy3LYKPN8ft01pWRwQf@BqsYQ6Qxz1acJ1KYFbrTkCz@qWrYAPANDEUR2m9Ad@0bwe4L63WDbyVVoBB9A7QVjUK8P6UOtDEQ3hgV1cCy3dZb0oBcw6q8BraY8VhM53W61cztzOFsPdVmuWZzsMdEBKseX4eqMLQeeegj7qTIsUarVA/@ThDcQ9UiLBFFB8zLw@Uykvry@h9aJYLOql9sBCc/qm@owknszkeCoV9Qc@1ZZHNmco/v7EGsXScf7U4hAXct/dPdQf@JHFQB0NYJDRgCY49kxuBycaWh7wiO30na7DtiAN1w79DEFtWlnM3a5j36ghAz2xqBGcuQD5i@M1xhD6Gus1GY6UKmyu8lkPw/YuQUpr@QwSiShEoFIUX31pXBhArlm5Tw6/vg@diJZLpwN3mj5AglAaIhe6WiFf8mAKZKQKfJYWMJjFuNHa/QAlNI2AhRaCLki4Owte6kkSU00tjb8Upa84Nyj@0pkusBb4cNYCR4hkh4@fPDx8vP9o94uzkZ7Lzb1n08U8EA7ya4IupPY43bC1bvGmicVCcBFoGy42L5ACYzBQ/OHwseeC4FYxisoRWME1fP4n9hWnZ0e9@GJhLjFUeWm3OAs9wsbHo4qEYGi3@2iMuHzaDPtz5J/eaDT0SqkUtPLeuKmC0Zp62XL6RjdF6aBj6PdTGpouh0c4ruEtSwHIeFOTp@BjWqA6TGng0OgPHDBeaCoORQOLcfA0WNW3uj2whXG@znTjasDBVJpUGywEsJVTQdlIANMb0FY8/XqSOWt/pOkFztdaWs@mZD/aXPOHuBsdE0ynGPRWQIr4wis7u3N2h01BSiOkRSARpm6JKRvsC/oMFEkaLEU73ycOSQscJkVZQTR6NcZBXJBSqVw6u63lcykwy8BMA51VwaE2ZWCMWj1l5CgAT3E6NG4Q4sKO1zLsjrolHD6yoPd9DEXN1J6fndl1UNDP7hBuOBFWm9ZrWj1eZjeTbIn48TJw71zxkHd9D@BdcgJr0nNZ2@LTtqH2h8Yq8ovlRD0a40Z9AAcXvSFkTmOzLZRuHo6rjaBXCTgGpRsQBYUbuzSjOOxseHxwDxKJyTo/Pdg4AQQaxA4GcO1gkhKIR6nIrIUWB/WBo4y92egcGstQQ5Ah4YRGO/S8Ng22d6F9QmJekF1eEJ4T@cwX6RzMeRuhNU1WUJrWiI@NO2MXJ8GsdrhsED2j8zgAjQoXkoc0W9Y0W3x0kiemUoDxZIBpDQY0mOCglVATMqkIBp9pQxvKwwFeYMe0ghMOAF9h9/ag9bdMPs6iDND4YMpwn0VHbmpX@XrKUF4DF6zRSbDwu@GJX6r0U58ANIIXzPzS6IIYOaRe3RlQpGc0ToGB9301URpORz0osdJislFxhqa9aCtxSyoWL9P8ZDQKgtKyY1fRjY2NaClajSbBdRdcO@i6i64EuO6SSyEXxlPRRSmS5MLQGqVAv3r0uuZDnsTryAMT7HFfW8OYUSuVMvWkUdPEU8dnHKoCKA@xFXwAnGi8UkFnPC5XL3GKA/TeUNn3kHdOWq41FCT4CnSk/F3QIENEALMYtWDXLKNNt54ig4oLxpaJqlnMjZ7V0mf1s6uzduLsOprE1PGyUQG7Chr9KDZQu64zHoLCU8uWFJAJ8VqmVC83K9F0dCsWKyh9yMiIxz8uxBMGp3UsagJPxc7OokBSQZ1aq@cSvElSj8cDQgEeYK23Qe@LRdWrAuTfjNfjiSikjUeTIM4q0SjQpYVE8KjQaElzJjqwJkBKaJjQNYTH4klRorkcbK5fN4e9qRuOEIxWgXaKI8@zSWxoDCT9wj37a54@rAjNWci@vsjjgVKIg16oZwynXCpKHNOz1NyCCr@/ulA6A2dkpD5XwdhQQ91MdCOaUhToQSiEQ6JiP7I8bMKGbTpjLzxCt3TgEHMH39PeGISlv9okCVxlDSWz1XNYdPMeQGfB9AiqBDjTo/D5Ih9Au6XCF4Uo9uY4yQC9Mi3DsEAu4hINPpqhERJc9Phj2rn88JUa5FamNCyNGVld23FNBUgCKSRaNEFLbKQqEysxDmnE6MZ4vgjdgyzJYLVMkIgHfccg2nJxHZpHGQ5C6cGuhSTHZlvqg/zogHhUeV24Zju1JdGkpuP2oIeA0qAk1oPaGoiAlOMN2@poAkmlGGh9c4HcKgJl7ZK1dV3Pt3Kdkh@GXAHE7kEloTVng2noBykaBMZFJe/z4RTftn189GCfjzmkQOujUQscf2oMnPYY9DFhbxybdjfJ9oGfLNsZWEAGP/3r8/6x44y4dQwvq0Y0uLFpDcZ9g8ZKFocz1qZrOU2nT0Mo65LO4o9dz@gbfPDGD939/BHoyE9PTypqKRQpZVwM1uaN43fLs@X0PAzP1dH0pD@t4nHGlDdzMvZb/iIuFDMiII8BY7GEC@rI999Gf79J4dyD8C@g/wCXb4GOKaxveg08RcQiRcQlXbgSRnheaelr9F9puwTxNIrHFa4ZtleaTv4Xo05nzjtD3ucKiqb@zDtL3nxp15xtFUYpxyPhOq@5OGFAeYoTLPdajCeEVzA13zP7/szbMSgmOLsEfXsf1SfQ6VGD5WuuTFBAhziJQBIap6ZYq2e43g1zH9rUUOGxpcgGtRPow1KouUibKSaGhsvUUsDc5lN6HpeeDpjENOqwU@UTvWhyuNzaSfFB680GgNiplv1VOKuiYU7RaBCNoBJukIKKSdPdN4oaLF7waCxaoiRlyUuBtj3R08rZZHu/nvKICB0mn51NPk7rX4DSjmulNu@kumYZs1tJLXrn47etHogNlpjMkwzqYWx3nH5b4ZNFUP@MmxlYEWKKPlitRQIffCzXX6hl4eIPsaAOxGVojdcNuAtVV70ZIbQqLAAEreGKvTlPXrxhNejBLlRv2LdGdXatjpxGDws/Grv24voxrlK6rjH1JLHCo8J2jz/5vJaucwjSwMAJoAKvrYm//BD0YNB7cJUnuHCdysgaUcdOE/IWlldTAakJzRUA@gCDZ1BmQUaiRIj6G/PNrCwdEwy2mImYe9NBkpnxa7XTN0Yj0@a8xWfhVpObT5eIbCqU/V0x9l5iaZqgAEXTwjBAscxOTh/sHx@rwKFeLLqPExklaHZGqwf6xqpC@5QMF77EPm5H2ceYJo7WqwRNCoyJhkgPzFsG5gZzAnJHUdA13Rh4xnEOogXeNO1DCbnCJQiEq41aI6JRACwG1vRdDqy0FP@nNrecBJ4lFmUJoiSQO3anBLS14urYtl6pHvQbpIZClCi3PWlpaWUzRuJrU4sT/7jWAOdQwWQiLRDKUKuxDZBuFFtmlbfseS2tFOuJTVavl/nMOCREnZ6Wqoplj4agJ59GIgEpcD4UVllnYfGrnwONeGIqjp8GPCsJvgVk3XFzerOVypu6HA@QVV6DBw@UF5FcsjiTo@gvCSIRQiuI5lcCza8zChXrKRnZC4uqoTg@AkF5cPouxkvJNipMi8d9zDigZ4aLpnOJPXE8z2r2adVnp2/xFVRBZ10ShBGQfMqEsytjwyC6YXuGdoaVMVvqyxfQCkpQOHU0YElhycgjFmdXSEwipY5UZG/eoIfMNnVGbCDjSltO32vfpgX5@NABZB@KlcNhnYOEhljWgaLjTJJ9421@3hRDuGGQuljQeZULOZyO65yWfe7Q7EvgaqRVLYd6ZpB6cN6/mbJjeT36mYsa4MDj6quw8wbNDv0siUCTEGJ6mzxoeFto2FCdRuqYHjTSvSTn@SUdc9k2zc7Y7tJcILqZ8uqWmEqxQJE7zaa1KioQAVdp@c8l0UBWYsvT1ayq@a0HB3igWwT5yW2iWdEXVwOxObpDJzWCVOL5X7/RBvrfrJ0e9Fc4Dhg4GqApYE0pnZWVJZLiC/0sr1g@XD3uWwYRhly3gWwZLhTJ6AeO5aBpSlxRQN8Y4AC/qHHgTfwBXXQNm3HM@fyc/1yeybIpLhvkdmtV3IXVUTwrmowBc7FNROA6l2VSIhKyvBLMCZ8QCRnuKHBvR8pfwsSImXm998ajMf8FdfjWSrSG@F3XNkXMdM5oaiYYpEbTMtdUuWucj9uOMjzvBmpxfkncWelpRlYBrURMzjbQubz4vICu1YXu3n@uijbrX1OX9LiNKzx77A2VJtn2bf5GDWGwJge3z39XRbHEDp/AsZpqVp9@3pMTBXRgFLE2IYUrP5UQ0awFMveN5hRVod6Hc1kwzw8Sp9JKJNKZFRO9w@Hq9GifUvpicXnqidri9Fg28pDiq0sVPjZHBRbrTW@pVeiurIHRV/R2yLlSmC9bJnAjajDDSGnMC5xfuVhaczPqY4fUGvcNd@Zaw@IzPPzJiVXj3KLbEG255fQtDxt0f5XU9NeqzfLC9b30E1qPYC2jZBsMUezHlcC1XAo4rRGu4VzBVu8h0/jaSVyhGuIT1VlFrJZzid@VGkQPjGH@u7xTe70Uq/eQT0q/1TegK1/ZI8yNOuKo5i28eml5Jv0sJ@z5UkRHrf5S//lW4I8nhscHb@Nsz@o7Hjuh33UE6rpABf67nKfDtLQMW6FR9rB7jRjyFx3MKtTod51@vtBNGfCzstbHbgdFv3i@r5ALhJSm3SKkfA3IsTXxXCnaz1Pu@W0VRPumXFxwGnKu6WWXSSoxqbO6dGAb4Izg8pIdpAuUUk3xMcQVGeNczqUx9Z@/QO@xirR@7zGckkYNCh4mKBbAMXK5lv2L5JZdn1v7/YTSDbDbtxUiVLnnfRP6K/q9UaVMT2sfmEJLp99fRHX6Y3NsLrU1jpovTdx@u8bOeH@k0qIYm2IKAGcdcK9IEOu1MA7fC2vsqvFtrTAxwGo3b9dm5oXaEBTwIVrPT8DxBB03U3Tt8XCuVucMNPt4Pcl6Q79JO@057DDkQ@VQ4RZlaU5F90z6rjWauJGHK7Yq2XQ6LXSY0FTO3Ms6YyoTpH1p8d@5jMlnlvMsLk7fuSHn8jyILOE1gStFkL7KtqfIxWLKtmxzNMXf95SmTcfpf0hNgVBtW6iNgXJJa1/X1dgNdUfs6mCz0QsPxzyanVXjFry3EeYl0Aft5nWVHp5req/aVHA2dYAzXfOv60dwQjNXt@WC26BxWIivhu2v1iXFgIimFtTtta2Oa6hO0@wb/DHJZ9fBK6qZtfDmhYaYBcZZYz5XPJvjjywIpeEUiGW1wVDpmQOTXtco@kb75djzHysjTRz8rgqemGYrNdk3W6siDC2QCzb@zk1Oh5SlkWODiTXChXdoqvRxaafwXSWB/enEpUQ@HBhdk5/tsE5SzsYscJkOt@xmzuWjFyW@NKcFyWYjzKtZAhrVuTn1/OdSgI@mLajX8eD2EbeFxt/CYdD3aO2r1pTe7GLtntOze2aPL@QO3lY1DuDHET@LYx3qgHW312IkmsJrzsP07Dv9/vvQE0UjF5SO01mK0z7uRsWtVB8Ed2o0IUA8bh2/M0ZcdqBjZavpmWPolzxn5AxNhd5WRe3jWA//XSVD/dnvX3QQaa2pDxTxn78o/Ftty67hjIZDejSG/bFHP5RUoU3Et@lNHb7mBcnOHLervnYGTVV4qmJBDE26LxcxTWvU6uHmbc7ZZtdptnrWbUg3TWNkW@cpf9SHv76X7YqUsZjyAL3VvgXkdacq8kslHH6Cj8NVlS4GkHi3FjjW6CvLBulon7QyNM5bHh8QRRcr4ZhwqDXy3dQl2oZeejW2RjOgoUVSwQgvn5lAxyrcxbKMlZoVbVqYiWGxXGMll5KSjgq5YqZB4dFWji/NLaALNbFMhv@sQihcSsIotODlQ8gtFhXRAKEVGroF/zn@mlsNtbSTs3vjrndTYPIR@zaoaPizVATudvEIJtwW6zCv71zSUjU6eWC2tzY0ng29mWGLx6oK0Psp3I8IzwZoY2Nz7YRLbu2MC8XT@orhWPBowAMqdbxydK1vDT3@y5TOynk6sXwKrPTFyUROtelyM1tUWdvs8PkRdN2mPA4cmsEF7URp4Ww/Dq@jmOcqGRdpttMFca/02SyyH3eVQrN0ZdJyxgh6U@WLx2bXwOXdD60Rrg9dwi/EzMtWNN0K@6tjw7O@OoaSrWJDPFyBz1G64V34@LYE3iOja7U@nauIAElBYLG4lD/mGgZ63ayLy57l4eqqwLFmyApZjjMxcl0DLIolMRcH9YNzJWatnu9YXBp72cC7M5zixq4pudaNuVsjGn8Vz1VG5ap1Z2uRuBwPhmNPPJbjQOu3wuPTg3Py9y4tAK68AqHLekZ/tHwMOzQYC/qZ6C5nzlV6@tetvtNlXy@kGahzoJ6h2r6Ece5Dx/0EFw259hJOpLzfc04Uh0AULvu8V1C3ZoYplm2N1o/zjEa4gMh/YmF4n4KbIlIP8Ve996EQlNPlFHl4uxUw20V8S88PnHfijN2Wic7gaJCwwSByNff8Bc@i17DNy7D9tnZeBzpKxx6PFHdsr@0V8mt7hRKbFPIhNmCxr@4/ehoPcwMtEL9NPzXBLBx7/enMtXI1wQKTWTaoaKvl6Hxs38p4wE8yOqbVybek2cXjllokrh84yyyhJ1PXHL23KQXCfzx4YLZwTvHWvB87jxzbgd5oCIJycGzy7flzq0CWJ8RkD3EDOtCnfWs2JwR2RSfEtQ1jaDahfvsz1/v0RRzwA2NkrOiKaNSQLMPAdSuvWP2m6b6k4cCQe5WxO4/Qp@aErI7VDMPboDJqtbiyjCN1c21kbi7HGzqOzX9J2qbhoT1aL1WgK6Cf959FV3Ht/9yIwVLLbb6oRxd8CYnZ5udHrCqrazadPv9ds2DJtviCAcO1TC/1EI8jIL98limgfXlrZcj2WhkyM5pAk70wPJrBX26EzEBqkw9YH9Qz3JaDc2TCsWbpTugMgVvEdLCdgK8qaALhJyCxjNZYnGZ4G1r9QXNAPytNiVBtHptN3IjUpIM3RsbkZmXyMSNx6kBouVewV98XV9io8yz2BOyU@O3d1pyFNU9Va0g/JKlXTqTTSh7FtszWawPH0xyi12zUei4cypx6TM4Vo9ihZkTjyymDNqUvbUnz69pAoembyqjnmqD8jtYNfPsnoiyZKRkPTJx@np@fWam6Ol6PCussn2kPhKtrKuI0PpAlwcl8XD9Udldqngge/o/ufyUFnXAjn/VPCQHRdfvcPiA/dm3xeB8OfOJ4o441OQK8cUfCKnGCxcpBEnjwloGurVWFgNqzx30@LtENLcoatMkcU@hEWEXpk7gemYppXyh0ZtvkZokcvs8stYvHi47MtiKOLMA5COWhv@UsiCaeS6ZWw7IRV4JqKU7YST4r1oYuI@6lLxlA33JGytCjZ2roPTl8eHSqDj1tudXfw50aN/S4uTMQ9EI6NFj10nBDM6F8rVrb8kap@yeasvfwUMUIK@jN5zoUeOCc3dxj5YioOMzTSBkrrSAMNUfLFcRPTx89TMx2hbLYXs91BmY8HLx3cpLEXS9fOVkaHE59AK2j40xWJj/c17T4EvZ9atO84SrpuSSnVZBOTbBGgRk/5Ueo3KpctZyh2T6dDs3PofNECe69Z/b5lYV8bFxYXWyFrLiSUNRQWVHNZ@OhZdtgbJtu8FxVn@fWEKVlix4p/li5UAU1h0zKzSzXHtatBVjUYlharFH4sERa@ia3jiwFWka3h66U4f19EdM0bRWdT4wO1CvLrays@QjLZo77zsV7TDKbwnhRAi9lBFylWLcuMt9WBiC6U/iDA/fCE5zNlQtk1gEIvPNLG/ylaU8NW6FZrnXqRQlS43K3tVG@br7HVFWw9ucCj1heOvsXrLdnsRY547dkfOqGkuzt3T@8LcGxoOX6WJ88fsqeGB6eF7I@Yhhj8z0wnmlGLxUct8LD6lZOtLZdAKWvhdcdLm/PJXZiuG3Hnk5un56jba/YtdPxvwEsfKNIZt@aWMv6qhYf13qyfAHSbXnzHR7OdE4PDp8jIwC9@/a/0LR0mk4JwqeW5q/rgPPNNMdjO3wsqpcUG/T5Hji@K8lT/bNrYzEjkYjH549HD@/B4ruPDDwgnzYOQdw3b9iG2B8EAcGWKbErCc/YAZXExL18kg@ixjavxB6eUkm7xn1McklmYo9VcN4gPzOvshnD074AVaaca3hBBNv0NwAxOvSZvWGkmoAs1HJpeFNT4R2ZZbEzipUg2yeHT/ZPTndPn57U0vVrOS72/3HUDAMy83eGfpxpy1AiQQzQGPgBmrSDsA/Z0YHUqNJ4frEYFGyhZJW5ks3KJN/FNJtXhpFK0Ua4lHIN@Ckyz41CQX6hF4ftl5ioLvYxlvj@sT5RVN7koGXKE2qixNLLMh4angfFEuGLR@JTKMtkMJRnLM48BEbrOk5b5OiZ7PaPn@PB7uHDp8f7zEdwxgqXVnvUqxRz/EhMFAuKCfXUsWhOvcKiIkkU6qpSiR5EgTBRNcpKtP2QjqME7oVoPnVw46JIvcVimwQfKBgNKiX1X7@Ruo6quDwsDnGjPlJRJiiPEdgpbin6s5@0@XHN/kEC/r0P7oDUcdqwLYntgis2CyJFqbkNV9/@QMcj077A4Fzm2Y0aEp3WDVx5iVra4vkwcTqygV/lIY7v8TMiBvGPeMXRBDyKB0yhCws3BXIcOngyzjwr49QknaKksl282gJ4HlgfkQDUx/aInz4h9qpHgI/UQEwk2SYhyw8Yl0MRozsbwMpNs2vZzLNBRTNHJfYS@Awt9hLfmaoo1eiNJD5ofqeJ0hsN@qGIN47S8VJno9S7X/tOqltm4J6k78Pbr4i3Drh/lbufp7Cubx63M8s/jAQeLSWw5pkHNEd6h27xsPkO4Bmx8FQgX/4xawBVc0GUxug8B/6r2EyewYnVPoeKAhaDWhI7f3l@pluP4dlWpVQK2QhnP1Ra7WhO@NKDhTOu8rl8VksBksqFD5AOpe3itioOMB4vAeNLF9aw8qIJ7LWzw2Ts8c1KvsxrM7VpPM/ILwJENyGudNlD5GoM0kCSWQoIq4pk0EkktDgmRXkU1aIoitoO9B4Ujr0MvtuCEDKLAbE4jUw85XSC17mM3Kl/VlsTr0gJHVi@KQApGnRB5IrLktis@tgZAcvMbdPlm1Vx6Q3vqXCi2uPXFdERaciD6s3WNNtj5Z@MLtqXiu2eg8qkFzu9cN3KzxDECYIoyctYtvacnY3O7HqK8yYDNv2hYNkwM9vg/mep7gqe5eXevXnQV2zxmC4kFrt3Yjuo2hxAYVhMT@mZlJaPz4qUzS4tkiiRyAaKg8cPvIHsQDSBmGiZ1ktn6O3u7R9@5ejJyY3DrChmdDEaSPLqTuJMUZO1euCIhos1XyX3D1Inj@4f@BUxQzofksCgk4iSaOtKMrNYEORsbexi0ZZhuFi61Rg/4xvoFvHN6OtQo0Q38NDSH5AvrU9TDmiV@WLmemEZtXK5dSjN4KVCoPf4FqEbqMbiV9e1@k71zI5Eb3LCkobwPKJuYSMA15m3tZlCZr9ZOCxYcK3YKV6I4oXbYmZ5W5Q3M3imCm5SHDnns9NkhEcoIFRePxsQkZKa8qOubH1HXJeenXmk82vP@Okr4TMnQgjn0@soHgJ16t@ghlJkdmKbOKysB3ZD32pK/lkf/NAy/2yl4Lwyfk5HLC6J87J5xjFxp9qkNFFpyjkWR2lHsJJs3flnPry4BA0a9bUnY7BfnjhDfn4qTS08MH3XsQPi98GYz1Ga7CvjAcTr0OPYpGEekNwKJAZKRgNUuf4EUkIcfzZJ4AFzkF8ND0ETBVcH7VxsEld75qRtdUG2x@JJkGgfa1qdBUekYaHpSDQ7KlOdzWphbVP8BDd@hcn@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@efPG28TYuTy6m8lmMbUfY3tEbWYMCRErbrMjwu/RDl8Qt/ayx0uUowD07wzsm5W05lapF6/BPQS/gwyPVqmpVvVt/@zZe24YyTaZnEby6jR3dmwcW0/X4iWVZKXY29Npt@Do9VueXj0b4J5GIKUx4KDXuxwaTDvlNds1ud7xvTLm/FRnj42Ak0j76@rNnz9DxjD7s9bFIz6EzP49Sw8hFmJ7W/@ynG9fJqyeNnT/75iBlbuDjCB/fuX6E7hMt9/HGxsf372ezSaASdz/5@pOv7e7uZh8kc09qubtZJb2x86d/srGh6zt6aqPueVo9Wjs//0LW01lZ/bMfRxtPnnzV87Ba8JNhGjjxtwBfDXWqc/YaPucdhv/kft0OuQ10NzuvmR55HQG2jkzprxFhvBVWSEsKfzaYVr27/d@@d/QqMopU9dQzF56jyKtIvhDhTnDAW8Z/u4hUIzsYLX8dmaYqlQo4t//bv4f01a8AHAyZ7sBPNefDyk8jVaVCSd5EqnlwaLoO@f5f3/jGbeM@92rwkbPbuny3Dp8t@uxIeHCSkk6lFmJrhTvaHcbsUW9kOviw@MOGBzPKNljdx7VEIlFXFfioDUqU0jT9jAZswqxF4y2RwLvMuA8L@c34RPhA2LMI8RQwFfEVdwsPYjXu8Wwx3rMln/Kzf@zPsRTJb9wzH1SrIAr1qr5VTdBn46xUgjI17jVSbLsgO849HNGKnslR9oI9FMSuyumCLieTyXsNvNmXTZCmyiQyIyDjNGKROcpG2OyNhb0izE/GZnE@NN4@fv78f/vz7//59@jv@/T9T3jGlN22OqktjvxFlX9YtSpXXfnqjF7usXSpUCqkGuz6LLZVq9aPmZb@5E00l4meYBkpEjuL@yOckeBTreKPjwa@VSPcp8pdMz8RUg1eKMYsyfJ4TEgmn6gR6ILFghuldlHnuHH8bn5q96CaZH27KNerek4/gqrTZKq4IuttesyJiBLdhc8G/NE/fO7i4LHwwd8N8uQhFHXJZyNA5fbPHJZSpFZL1c06KLKs6gO5t1HaKJTyJR0qZTXg8irQkYuwMFG31YKqg/h4W9tgx5zX6yzhf84St36eqmpDOMnh4FdRnElEivwjfKoSi1zBp/52q/Z2izX8vGuioSZ2lHo1IVCCh9q4V08o19c19XmiXBb/O9XAWaYPd0FJ6teKsvMcYNVuQuVA6VdtPN8BsImd2k7F2aOv2kAaK/Xn1drOfFqR/N69BArZewCgulln0awTzTv34onEpqJs1FYWAeDWYwysAqjA653r6nVt5/p6Zwf@d@j3WjzB93rnxj89Zp8VcWbh1GzOaqnqWepMsE0d3tVUFX3U1Bk4qvCEeNANSREFpJwU2WJbkSHTtjPgYmZJ29Izqdzk4/w@qEa1uoIWTEWpaflcXeGS6oXKSgo/mFor5OMqiqKG02ngXjKVvZAiL959@b/g9@zdl7@P/T40y6IUSW2heVDkVgL8PLLZo0eP8PvItuEfvo/4x0Yf9HiEfjb/sXkMP07gzX2oPZBUKOTlRkKb6iyyI@e3USz80o1PNBr9Jy/04naUW9C45@qFB56/tOzzT35p1UeKvCliO295jJdJilC7h7qA9lNF5xX@NF/h38PX@PdqhH@nLfw7foV/7PQ1/h2P8O9RE/@eePh3@gr/dpv4dzrAv/uv8O/RCP@edvFPilRA2d68m@6nW2ntXDsHh8XSLkv30j2tjZZA2mTpaXrK0gNHa4PLhL80uKx0h6W7LG2nbU2DQHCMWHqErg48uvDXASgu/Fk4t3qupVsMcukDUH4nCz3fgCCLn0k1MCHlFyaoxaqmptW8VccTuWtyXS8WmIoUVhu1F2fROh71qBezrDk1N85esIgHKnU5kjo7S/HBAaZny3h49/V1o7H/@EGjkUJRdPbIOZr9Hx0Nwq9r/wdHzqMjZ@DA/9HR0SNmVhP3Eso9@FSqiR3xuBuplu@elRRst76kiKR27p5VMwq68wlo/Dr6JT7wM4MIz@rGmRRloKlclkkfKl9elC/L5AhewdEoBxFENO4Az7LQo8Cn7CtUl/C5uCRP/EHn5bOzwMUdqWeXZ2gXgMEX/IPCGX79B/i3/t/1/@gpi9XqoN/Erq53YvSJ4188fnV9dS1@q/FYTLzEduAPPeAdk1xdV9FJka7AVYvF6/Hra@4Hv7H4DgdYxTx2qpR4FhEafyTIk/LlP7F/2CfmLT5neCh0aKb@7GySTsfLTf8QWpylMt7QhGm8TFeKbDZrWv1Pf0xHDd@NU6RctlzWthh/0bN6uZz137YL5XLBf9mMxYo3P9X0XS0PCk42G4@Xy/By1webhtcAbAHA@i85gGp6RovafTlydXhEh/CCmMhF4lgiLhhiaTqrG699iMol@c6dmLiG8e5u/M4dvZh@8ybwGQ7BS5vzajTalttooH/mzRu5IdPMeTEH7@nCmzcgy6Jxx409xttCIKOYorGP9SrlWXRcIMQ2BDMtpc@w6BmeMRq5sdfWMCnj6lZPjtNh/um0455Ff/bdb37zLFqpyIpMvlkNAWAuLLezk89Wq/ksuPMFoJS8ecXvtegmilr8ejMlc2oweTMaEUFaYTvOZWMUw6GHY3er0MA9/LCr6whVO8vm4jGQrnFQtK4j@Me9tWKR@7NsPlZIFMVfZSPOqqAD8D@0TzOJ7Nb21r06o7/Jsg@K5PKVWdGuK1dmCYf5rsstccUZbisz79zJFIGmhXT5TGo0Huye7jYaFVmWsTuEH/Qk4S7hDTFDN1qjCs8V6zUsX/0sGi2V7xFzaIUci0TLIp4ShV6CFYpEBsnq4J5RKLukCeN/Q9LpiT@SGAvaAE@8hZzNvk8e7u7tnyb1HVBp9IPdvaR@8vR@RMPX3OydgjP4fry/@@DoKSR48nB/92T/k8PP958@AX@PXc4@vgQWv7Nn2LXk/ZI9k166rw3TNMyxaTYux@PLV@ylZTUsIGx/bFmW03WZZzZM0xxCNP9Thm/L8oyXLw13SB/27offfvfD/@7dj7777kfffvej7//sy@9/G74/ge93@fO7/66Yw9@fffkvfvfd7/wIPP8TfP8Ivj/92Ze/@Q3@pfc/hu9/Cfn9sfiG4vGvBLB@5Wdffu/HP/vyV38A338lvj@4@f21ny7/fv9bq7@Y7nu/uz7Od/89fH@Pw/Ljfvd3uB8@b8T/HR7vV3/w7jf@A///U/GHzh@9@40/xh/x8s9/8Kf/5d03/6OuF/7037771vfefeub7771nXff@qf6u9/8t1o6/PO7777/B3/1h7/3V3/4P9H/T@j3997n/90P/vlf/K9/8b//xR@K70/h@x/A9dO/@I/AsH/7Bz/E/@/9wd/@0Q/x/3/@13/7B7/@t7/yb8jxW9zxf/@rf8d///rX/vPf/PZ3/uqn3/ibX//p3/zWH/zV//Gr/@dv/ue//u9//6//x2@i52/99K/@6Ff@8pvf/stv/cu//OaXK36/vfb3y/fw//Ifwef98XwfOO9Trg/1@fIXwufvQ41ZLsAnwN3/7N1v/jIw@G8w9u7bP8HFkfBd8f8TXaM4P@Fv/x9w6DfLjCFpcMH31999@7tIov8BSAT/Ab2@E7zMhfCX78xegKy/vZAoYpbmO8@CXkhsgYWxVSyKDjQI3qGUP/vyX/44yOKX56HOhUGO30FJNRf2HZRx7374jXc//qfvfvhb7374K9ibKdlicjepaOvHnqELVHLvEQ8j5t8nHkT84gvIf5KgoVIlgW/sCxH4xRdfSJM3KVyNe@8N@H5BXvzDeBCEMRHkhwl/XKkajsOdad@5id5vwlkjGRKYbYJUgS1fT8ll2CQhMJrgSBw@wR8iTbbIOcFf8sXgiYQ/s/@ZcyKxBMbhH7zaxHeSQ6QTWXCnlINsEpOJTy9SnBhXVvjA7YRmkSjfbJFhCSaTxAQsUnBADgkIup9glUolgQkrHB945ahVC4xQSSQqUG5MzdMkGwUEMblPUCBlJXHMGluVCU@YQHhVnxwJCb2OZU2XE4XKA8iwMnnAEBYCJ7AvXlSqhcqkiuDecnokJon7hBMCqyQm1bfwXiGYCRxUevAWUClUEolqATPEQvLqSTZ4JeWocFT2BEuIOoAnjdDeY@xjWSvIfEZjAwnGY@NvYhb7Ls2x3YXws8SWKA79@076bhHBNygrkQvj4XdJVbzLtUeMAHAVRVVVBl9FQWzuQfCEg0pQtvBIcAgJ4gjigMAD2BDrIkH1m6AXyD9S2frgT6Iq8dJsbm5KkaqckY9ohicBVrt7XuJ3U7zhplGJyfmijN4mrfzmpTM3n9Cww9aDLfjV4H9/gxZkJ1iZ0NqM4uBelPH82McJ/r13b4t9DKWn58xPYkoi42RxcB0LupNIyDrkWnUS0nOQbhKwLwF6I6mTCs0rJaRkkjG1EsEwdnR0JFAjj@cVKQHcr2c0fMeJgPF4HIEUqppUk0nxVOlJHqpwqBQqnuom0pwGI5muZ8tg35QZerGwOaKB3Yqeb9@@hcqiRRmlQ7AomVifoWcLFAgefJNivz/1dwPo2aLEzWmm5fmtyzG6XC7O4hKLsa24xJfvciSC6d6oXihE0RWHOlFjW/5ynbwm@WOENEQYpOA2XiEX9wP3jtje0aNH@49Ph/U6k0y69c9sDF2nZXreOsEcw3S7jx/w1f16MY9oRGo1zPm0pKNYkvZLaRKahw@OD09KjNNE1FAsgBQv0/ivIEVRkyLD4bOdiFjSIOM1FI58gr@lWfljejGDGVbLUqRlolkCDIf/rCw98rr3nQnY8klZTmp5NNHiNILKpK85pVLlrZbdluBJ72OGxyLxPZTQOnENuLqzQ0STqlcKjXqjEyo4L1WrYm0Q06Tqyf4pJDg9YpqeVhlY@lfZbT2by@b0TD6f29a1bL6YzecKGehr8umcrmvFbLZYKG5fS9Uv2ERFXBVw9yt90@6Oepu4Ikc@S8shemzW0kn80zMZ@AWISS23Xd/Y6F8piOAZscUVLq26htcrBSnwEXyY9JHEPgIv@EAeuF6KicVqh0dlsWIITyuI8WVDspaDxh2XzoCRODhpGP6U596G0JbA8g99pcjG178@YtUqWNzK4YEUAZHVY/4SGsVqqz2VmKo9dk0K7TLWtj638KYStW15w74xhYaaVqXI9fV1ByAdHuD8Kr3yFG38vW6RTxPc1xND@v8//6CfHX6eTxV3RThGu4J7w@gUEWhw8at2pe206P6icqdSq9N1VOW22nTaU9UbTUEQioqsRJt9p3Ue9QMtvCAStztWUkZKbaB4GTmNRqUSTaWid/XtXGkj5aZUOr6MxTrQXO/q@W3wPLO5b6wDPjn0eT7vVSy1VR@pR8C2kE4v6fnc9Y441K8KZULUqojIlcCvZDu2eY37GUpGB2TxVYsvWivJeq4gl2vl2ft2Xi7Xr@8NzLZlsLM0rmG/Wpown5ev/XiQtQkNjrZIxQZ4iQ7uhCmlz9LxFYnTkBhQJkylHXGOUJUWYdVAbNT3oTeo1Xf8E4ag35Z0XdEzSkZTtAz@3@LQ8f/94@vwr@MvpMro0inusnsM1Q3i0WYP8ajjkcNOHYdutbpvtlbE2OsZtNpsz3U87@8R575hn/OgBxY/2iYI@tTA4@y9gTXqrYjxdDjADXqm@48GYX/QBASRB3mE@/Dj9h1nWYRt9vTJilI@Cg6TA2Lw0@Qg@vHhJ5@ehp6n@7t7n0p5dv/o8YOFR05EyrGH@wenwes2D/WT5gIQX9t/@HDxVTwi2JHigOgGy237Dk3C5ap3wIy4I5y5/MyZRuczvpPK8oLlk3zLXEk69bdXUfuwmiZr8T2TaNfQeQZCvdG2i5I0ZLZzybbTrO30@wbe6NfZAM@egdtGTOyw@3TxJGZ96bj9NjQxc0N6hDtUihpeW4ZISJ8CkMG4RZuHrZGEp@O08a49HIBv4nXhY7zPcoUnPNALna7V7Y3Y6NLxI0hNw2Dw/dAPpDfDn9F6jxHPg/xuhPRvRpcikjEyIoUyMGy5bY/v3NGeuMDc1UK6VDpLXwN3Ve6b5eZ5aWh65tCr7k@A19iYPQXuN1wUkr3NFFq8bDMn51uyXjpg2SRTGxFjC@netSo1dgKKSn14zAo4ZtwyMtkt0FuxtwddDWen//q3f4K8u5UCMRXRZBkXzG5okkoKnl4s5ArFjF5IFoqFbE7L53JJTU@C/rxdBBUnrRW0fCFX1JKFbDGTBY0JQnPFbSnCVyOltggkPEsA1m7hDVs7pCOqvaoU4TMx7HXMiLOIEbyPmWxCGhnvVIZOBnfkbVkVWc8yLc3APACIBmuxyMHBXvrgQJbv4wvOP@@lZbmNL7lCOr19X5ZNCtkDrU6XZYenKeBxBPKIv6TT9/dkecwB4El@stzDl/08ji7IsoUve7sHB5hPB190TA/RznkIf@n7L9sQzcaXTIaGJ2T5VQAO4u3yjLKE6T6@YJ4YcsBD9iBMlj/x8UmnAcIxj8chfOqXdXdXlg/5y@4uhuxRwXMc1c/wZZc@sgzVju1Clrvg6GJvJ8tNcGLrkOUWuFpTA/zwPjM87s0eGbI85QRCEsnyhGIbrXMZTHDhj9l8@umnRm/UNrv8M3X5swWoQYg1Ge8fND/5pNntNt3p7v4nxxiyt/ep0ZmO3Wa3KZI1G/BxIA2EnA@mix/A8bDRMPpLQz6DEHshpDFtmIhbw3gFOIlPFzMZNPYgZA9Clk1icWjwGUDUJn7uD@B532hSiP@hEHpOmk25jIyKJzbQpaTQZuh@0OTAaLlOGd8nlQ3GorFoclrLp@tlCmAD0NDS5Wu6jTRGl8CjORu/mtYmlXS9Mqls63z1Qycmn030nCUnNwZ3tSIoX8ZdTc8mJiXcl@t0oiyqaHdZTLuz9ZrFHoOalcmW5LO7dxW5ptXv6lqhlN9@vjWW5XgJf@9mtksQMR0FYw9/4rXt@l3Q6WZJtrcTRkovbW/Hy9dAjhH0nk00Mxux2KVpnMfjiC4aJVAEfhfqlMpplTuxSXJS4Xixabw8qWhlfhIRS9@A1cZj78atkeNyiF0AN7mbLtFtq7JWLMiQfyoVi8dBMpEQgedsbdOzr56en55@ATILzD1hLD3hV/iVxesnn@6pYD@JNzyuTj1AFdlx1T0ULHMh/DQ13@vUnIzUT6ELBHXV98O9Eq7TV/cnYMKinu0H@IcQqeLoGPX00zk4KIB5zrjVtEznD9gtk@FpflabGZUquIw2GOkk7oz4JXW@jWq10qgM@IWp1SDVZ/zG@RmYQ4/jHmyApeRXuH9ABDQq6etZ/MfjAbvPI9EF0H6yRuU@9Obpso2n2Jr4uskmkYlUbeNBf/cr96/GJRwkuS6bFRMvlpUjuD39rl0Z257RMZ@YLu73PjzahF4Gdx2AbWCy@CY7o2to91AZv1aqLrPncIkZSrWJ4wpznqFXJB9o5l/1CXNFe2Fw8vgaLJvY83j5Fby5myzWVu@DMZItt2P3WSMOXukXnRcdprN8tky3c8UIlpEkCtIVr/FK9TPQcTjg81IJkBGccA5AMSeAa7UpwIgPretyt1LDyG/wZ0eR5bqi1N7UpaqiPJOq0HjL04hR8cZNOg6WpZuans6XJ@CnbWfLPdasNJ9Pym5lCKY1K/eh9sV4At/iY5SBhkApgPP6DYu9@@VvxHeUXIV7lgnYmz7oEQ21UZnMqipTqenZfFLPZ3H4IZ@Br5bUMzqu1E/q6WJS16C3hl4c0sN3G96z8IU40JnrGg5SxPoxmTE5mZ6kVS2pmVoSiJ5@YbVfxJPnMVBIiGjx5MjZx6ttwQMZCZiXXuFpxBP6Vj/WdpixoxArgzQpUzmNZI8NLfhBOMem0efx4wrLbMX6mzGMtHk6Hu7X6qXS/mT4VQiKKa/u5hPb6cTreLwcAxEar3jmK6lalqoofIgKww1gbTH2wrzxoJbegHJfKQ3lGqp7tKlt66XaeLOmaFDA9JvujlyV6wxq7JoJZQeFCtd3ZhrLzK@BWjVeEs20ol6WVFpjQNlpMb24aqdIXMLVbQKgNBQCEanLYmeyv@UtFo1u69FoPFrGIdoNWYysgRTk902DOI7e0e7KoGPJJbmoY4SZMKVdTemwmnUtob3MskUpciVdX13vgNmZosVmoA6yDXIpavWeFCkxBrremTg3I7XB2IeuYUvsVJ/z5xmucgW4Ep0XVWN1WlliWmgrsc9xB@ddFgXEDHdQ0/VMvaZvQx8IctWPqutaGQegI7iaVq0C5b0rwG8nUcXND5@x6dRIKD5l7zDWTWxKVOjIItl3K7vd492y/7aHw15nkizL5agcuYpGotfwJ0X4jgud77hgkdCeC75Ks2UCfd5GSF6wvSt/UKWE9xnEjBKXDrV6/O1jq39VyCjc7geBdX0d2UxRjYiF6@XPXug5qCPb8Veyg/0zgh4BurdcDgfwIqkXQ@/reiHz6PDIfuAemP6S1WxDrkZYWlNwXXi5JHxzfCGrXCzosn6ejLB7kXKEnStRrUSL3dnwpPh8@3nh@aOnR0@PDqTI2cabDQcHd5lPFvbW/spXIWI0k40ydlaJTCrZslhMVK0q2o7O7kIvwPDS8I6WV9Jvqpx9qxSQ1yHk3S//IDvZKcC7DhpuCaowl9CrVW1LZ/HI8N2Xv49HEVztf777kEU9Y8r@7k9@rG//3Z/8a1qiE70uezR4uB2BmOjU8tuRq6vh1dU1fHhYLlKPcKSy23Fw81FrLTJbT19KGcbWdiKr37PLKRFX29biEU@JiLH57VzEeyOC9HQBgvzBc/KS81gFkf1jK6dr93aQKbRgGw6bzdGaXhG4ovDoxRvG4KVVbXe7lk6uVIqV3ips562yw97i4PNbZYO9qFRxwlTDzTv@COtWtVpFKCxaTaS2okzPQVjtulxPMBqhBWPwubllb53Nc/TZBisWbfA3vS0xvH@25YFlt2XTn7nlefDqv5lbLz0m4wREKtVu0xktOybLVaH@t1KAzln83S//pq7n/@5Pfu1N403jC@gbisViXtMjP9d@/nOIsGbXuG@a0WA0bu9GR2DSsRUX3KotsCbx1uMO4/F9Aw9NOgZqg9W1wV7HN@kCdSGqmgY/iqgdo2hbuKk0SZo1HRQSL0tSoIGS5ux2W0mCwbbwiHFom9KV9BEGQdfKKiAupY9moMBjAH2p02p4/bE7pEXqMUqn1ZPsDiSBHD7Cs5s2aDOskLkKiKnU1s2kHGWPqEZaERuYnocnQUEvIn0ESR4C29O9ZWxo4L5tjGnZIORVjEJ4UkC7BnnXIe8@T9Ag3xiVnkdIMo4dT2SDdi19BJoBUcECjYFZOxChDILlIyAAlCEmAFt1tsMycXZlJRLl2TFT17jgF4/EMvw9oxImQ2ht3KPsJy5jPPACrR6vJkG@EDUM6lnI0wfCYfAJyQrYBZic3lDlok3d7w0KYNEBKjEqGrtzZ4ZVpWK144xKhPDPrSGOSlE92MtxBWC@TfVxuyQnmZ1IYGV/NM92QPEEoQtcp/CTu8qhpEzG12tJgv/3ZlrkyIWqooAyFkDUF28VLSAZJEay8zpssZ0K0/TtOAuQbwHuLUKKjpcKDMWzyceq/oUfeA0Y/jziH@8L0uc0PNIn@HZx0zCDbm@MZ6vi0TFcGIjNvvxwGJRihyM/dZAKimL1KXbHcsGIoQlR/6SpWEaLY7LZyVyEBy3h1bMM19Lm4vigVBibwdPAM5VEPhs0PN9yoEK9oWPTIUx0YAQuUwaOABklzrLhaI/tSzyLW9QNJQ5j5NE5Nsj5iDEdKkXXm1FanGFsumDp@rRJMrOrstagzfQiixGj0Zk7dgAuTokI4aaJx5@5TrNvDgClE9NkeA6RV0qluqAVjZt08NAjC/iqd2BBV2J7KXGTXOrSOrdSp3iWqOJ0QIUW27gjqEhh8@OTmeKQn77jnLO@dW7yAdzY3CZ4j@n5JCitSaDs7AuELeFYsZ5JsjQEJ3ks@G7DY5s7C8lQ2o3YNH7zmdE2Yg2s0TfUJ1ku3hJ3Ydgh@tLnjSTMYG/q@cdo0GEQ8K4GItcUG@grUdy7G5wMIYkDQSp0FoWKg/jDGJic/kEa6ARd3LyAGIomYR8DQrPlb0nHVgyl/Yg6AGp70LLwTK2RW8KDFAATtx1rQdMTAt5mH7OMLtHtPHTKiTiRBGBg1VfmoUMYJMVyeKM2VIzKtz@BXIHWOWhDGG7hFeyH6X3uRjeddzZjb7YhwGGnQ3lVGG8W/ksu9IKtA/mZir4BgXnAcAkmGzE5AWATclzmoIP0i8k5t0skS0rsJqQkQwiC1ACFVAX/GkkWOjRbgoD7hsdPVhSnb11eXqp0DNzYtVTTw4OkPbwbMzXsWqATO6mRORiKK3ssvMRNwJ25FH5@PN6YendCd5UW70z5U5I6XkUsPYhFO14UO8cLPCe5O6DjY/DcFo8Y6sCiM9ZbMbFagvOfXk9e@fxXQv5TCtFrBMIYgpkkp8lWEoAlm63zZOeyXRYBF9QgATjUoul74smLrv8y8HyXNewEMZwRbQrw35v985bTd1Ankfnw6ixrXkI/5tR/Fe9DawKJbPOS7bquMY1ReBxjIwPHpqT2sCl0@xQCTuhm2BU/B9Ca1Kb1ueSTIDl0asE8sotnw0hX64HyQyExfMLDJxA@4eGTWaZ@trVJnatk6HWNxUGuxyPF/JgIZurHueYHKM5CCDIo1kzjIDDmdM7vGr6tCqX26c3foB4rPmMATwyB4GYsVXt@Vjur2555uVVPpLrA7DIRAmocQNfqRNPLduBG6vcv@kPHm/Oy8SQ56JUE3ujV6glu4LyCZQwqiBiD08vCw7@6A5WPA3GFQBQYIKAeBoGoGuyOYla8HBwtSoHAODV5RmOOWE0gUyftSwQJP1CXOOk5YcOA6iFA6B8UCdCEEOa3HH5tgC8dnrl4b7IfV6GTzgd4CE20HgVKLjQVLmvKVEkhrBTFRxPIjupqZbEofjhURW0hKFTMa1H/YfQ3Phj9DrSL5dgTw/IOoyyFmwquxQIVQjQXoiqrVkL1Chiktoy@6ULPtc/1U9FbQzZbKd/M4PlgEbxLvCUxFqr8VpzXD23Tkm25FLDCtFKBIk4rvFnyduGTlBM8SOaJZFOfEUR6LkAARnppMlMkm4STTSoVLjjYZEWyyxCSE0JywpPw2JMVSNZFMrCegut1sXrqoJ3iyi8Z4Gm8GwU1aCgzvCoR56pf4gFZOJMp8pzJHOICwUOoYiOftepLc6@FkA4JrQUAyIg3ALT5DUQlaVHgaUrwFsgoTkpfRvE3wQZcVgCDkQgu80MkYwGTkQ0MCr@coH4A2q6cqEmyhqvO6C/Nv3LS9/S/2k3P9HxMbd4znVz4@0fxrCNlQw00pH1o6SwKZLRknopLped0jghe1tdzQKtrXjostkTZBv@Ufx91qtl3mqmBgetD8F6S4JbquG8/4JQIuzd0RsbIyWZL3GiyiO2W5c9tBqtrO2CahA@PBV2v7ZieHR1Bpbacrm15ZhLvxeYqu0mrFfgJ1FJYTxZOx5MkMQbJzVgEzfkKVd1GA29KazRintnvxEvBolF8VZE9o1EJ7V9whdKDeBJAj4Yxp/nSbI3it8PEc45FslOrdR47GorAKGSyy0CGtUD/h9AeaDDMc2aWI524iqp0cxSjc857zsDpgtY39lQJUy@AP5zBRoSM4ZBwSTIDTdpS6LBraiWxVtKIi6SffXBS9pkeM@JBen0ewBwxksxdpDFS1l2SXWNldjyZn9/Jh@N7Esb3ZD2@ZIUv4sxN8woP/LCsM7EZBIg4QyNzOxpYdJBb7RvozKESeKNexRO8N4ptWn/VRkx3IequiK52gD@SwZsHbwHin6@i//oK9JPvv2/1GXh95MkU5M0AlwXG6AR6z5/cjEH0w3hciizJLmDtB@@ZF8TFyz8OUIUANZYEl42HRULDHILZ7QVHmPuAb@F5XEZ1g@9pbVWFBy7Byb1IsnN9dRU9aLTNvjE12zERMxmC65f4GAw2klfvV3AUdCT0HG7rxaDvigeh0I0j0Xmk0gqWMZIX8fhqtuJRrIB7aKScMDxcTT8MvyGacYivwkerwQ6IRvHgMvvCwuHP4XQ45ecR9@nQdF@O8v6H1yRuRr@dIEAHcRxLcpZtfJ34PI4FRXqPHiGIq84XGY8L9SHiSZw36/DDSHR7SaFyQ4kqfi1L82frL69xa12Nh7jC50k@b/R@LHkb0703z4VYjQObibC9D@tCbkDGFRmtViwMkfusrTHHviET0I/G6ewVvUpjiUANUpKkG1lkbpN@EZfQMj6EJw44fQ5PBNg1Rw3OUH7ZcExL3OjBKGRgDENai/ABJR2ghKjISS7QCMWSfDdEv7oO8mytzLN1I8/WXJ5BC5jPMhRJas1lKWoBq2ddFfTNzmiFdMYgtJ3hsU5sw8d2DBdHK66iVrRkJVn0IloCgRw1o6X9GAjlaDtaekAOL1o6Icd5tPQZOGZtK/omWvKbBUZw4ZUc99BfiHB8b0VLe7H4tTQyzk3Pz1eNloI6hTh3@StRBEiB5QatEafYbEcUc@Sa0LGRUplkyDFeEs0nGodJ0jcN//y2DDp1HwNxjHOLIrME0@Y6jVCPwfOBbsM/1XlJSy6J3nz/6IBWNAVRMJsE2HjhNAQe1PBIdF4YccQwlGY04AkIotwsLceIhXqy90RH5A4cSpU8nz9RTyV9oB2j8BpErs8yoStSRHq/vuZB8Ap8Pzwx8So8b6DjZ0cY4ZxsfAlaSNQX0TWFwrqex0XUfriGaKx7PhLev@pH4bVEYEMyHXQ4mpzDzIbOcJ5JKBRXxlvhNDQoxxslcu9CMpIKomWuCCZvUTIUDOHGH19XnFA6RG1OBGFgLV3nrSzoF0gWY9BM1oU0Vd74AIWQzIEWbrbO6fqZB8JJ8bi4SVJfsaob8tPyLElyzYtJSKziqTpjY8RzD4zXfTxr58PMVz/lBMdaYggglDLIhctX5wP0d4fr775C7RNhIYNlivXyrvSmer22l13AvD/L9mYFYmCSPYgvVY6CHGYkB@sgpJmv47UbKj4u@eBKPs80gL6g7ftkC2yCW@i2aFtwWKgluBfznuc6eJ7rqwl1UyPpX6i@0qJiTgIOL3iA6axo63HlBV9WxRhC49tG/4Mr2J2v4HDlITwqgLtAct7K3bFNq1xmbRvENvdBkaqVGBfkNF0aVPPME8Q9Td0G07bgcdQ4fnD0@OHXoNPd3t6Oiz56OsMPWy2OtQb9OIdMC6iD/mCJ2aIn8UYJnOzG4Xi663jjzJZvyBIurEEZMCAXn/1EG48LWRaS5wttF9LxuCGKCljns2ZgzEklVHUM7LItQdcREMQcxbYMAcRXb4HeSbLW4nR3QqOB99s2GtR9NRq4eKnREL0YVo0/Ix7/eWQjNfZcul@PX/xxKUm0HZ49OGLPPt09Zaef7rODp3ufsa8dPWXPdh@f4rbmJ0/vPzzcY/Ddf3yyz6S55ZF4SRIalEDXB2bLxBvq8EiyLCPIe85wyuVObC/O/U@MAfvUaZk4TbXjGYN7Pf6i2uaoylPtgzk6xTFMiy7CGlgjXG9BtziBGYvKTZt23uF6fwZxm2DTDtDmHThtq2NBXAlt36Flev4GMNa3oAZB3vqbRJNcScILm2jpEF2thiuwLiG5AfFx7gbAGHz9FV0hbHk8gdlWmSBc8PlgCp7uHz86Ybhxfu/o8YPD08Ojxyfs4OgYXp987fDxJ0DPw5PT48P7TzGIIj46enB4cLi3Sx4cgbTKcOv6y7E3WouCitGJKq1znPmmm6KDt/lRb9Tg2aVBexA9Fh3bKH0so2@9NtvRsjT2UH3BfY80VcBim7vHn3wOfT4zX@EMpz8VTOsP5KceXRy2mWY7lBs0liq0t7JortDtKVqc5iMGU4b3CJhl2qUeI3eS@cBpEU/bMpm8h2tUcOybb2antuyDhow2ADaC8hesVBjd/xGNJncIZBVya/UdPI6Q58YXEYoXTHrPX2pSlohiYq0MAsX9Coc2jgdp5cAD@B48dJHtyOURWCbw4BFYlnugKnqIa0dYTsQYj47GKJ5Znnu8HAwPaFqYbQce9w2yYgsCJ15vVKUGC@5Pwq39fbrlhY/y0O1zhteyLEriUXy8AaXf5w3D5HdvgUzkU4m0tg1iyiBsOjjVIJa98asnMRS4AdcJGZ2Rx2KVuMpOcXGQaVv8fp1u37D5EqjZ0h3iPVbAw1sqYpmtFdxLQztAhg4xIN6JNY9HkO6B0ArN900HKe/fyNEQayTpbjh/CdptCNy/gcAvAgYAKXOWTot6KtpqimCcjmDlmOcAR@K47dtwfGDn9rhlziUQq7ZiL63Xr@OCyMk5O8lfp0jYQRW9Nl1QK2kqs@O40MZJrNJNHigFWz1nOLJ4HcbmS0AzTtTNQWzs2CC3F5XqXG5Ih8UcbccOZdoELl6RaxOY8n1yJY7nc@eB@Jpd6wicD50wX3eH6BhNvCl5NneWxEmkSxOHX0ARprlyHPycjggTrn9KM9nxluHNcIVK9cH9M@XtiyReD8fFAr@R0V90iF9gTMwLmgfN89GCRRf1LtHS/Gt9vHETU4s1eEJaYiv3gYEd2LPArrvXKAdhfLnxTX/cILPoT55v3lR4KgUlk7ik0@vFZtItyWp@lklKU2diCUhIdgKyIOtjvk@SYAby@h5uhcFaKANFbJQjaLcvXJojRIhfuua4A5JF3F0oqjuAH2dVWlExu8oVd7aE6yP1PHa/kqjGU7MFJSxEzpgvopM@ZC0eDy1Lof7qBrgH68GB/H5/cIW12PHu4YOgPVgL7YNwUxKrYfFuKQTr/cG@XQOWd26/EFgoe3I1YN5J3oQWcHrAnMnNSLCadn2OL27UHbU9AIN9L46gBEBDuY1tmqL2D/@N8QTxMJiZQnRy@mD/@JjJ3D6BtCD30GRoCzGIsDfYk9lqW8smYacGSlNgLAfKk@8zt6LN/6xrzEuJt0JUCB0kKegRCIvZpcUda8KlnuhZSIWg1fckEH3KzWN35csgryYAX4MNCMjOKi1UQGlpMSO887G88CJwQbck143Da/hphTXvu/FGQHcaBhReE2R0cWfJ8vp7xvXjkp8PV7DMV2MqcBs0aehvwE44gYyHEFFV52twTbX4VYqL7LmCHfFphwu/0vMa9t@foYiRuBLOdeGQWBfKsUCN68ebvppDCxKxGzBwpacI5CuaIcAX8eSzE67Q@KzTi813QaBk4h1x98JcAcnr1@Xg0vLYrJ@sBAp5uK1tEjY1H8s6js4K2OXVkT7GtdD5RfGwmBVI27VZKf8wWfFeYi4nn@ZLC@MHAuR8Lpe5DfZiKfzkyt8XNu9DFuXnaDAE@34G0pt6NLwPnHv4OOmHzxhgDen40nq/wSwkBFVnSZ8yV3bqjML4AS58XAiQwUO38dq9xVzjbLKA23LovEcKQ6coN8oQasJBQXmruUH96/XZoUC@Nb@ND8@PNzaMhEsHr3FV/iPH9czZrrzQSSshL9y/Ou9nuq5N0fh@pgFCidE2prWb7Wi3HV/wykuFgTTfFi5JR@xO4stuk/5YA2VCw4sq3rSJo3vlxeE9RSuHi3pw@HCfbdFheJ25sUjZleMh2bNh2esQIBlM4xLYfdAevo@9EnwBh6QPEshEu/liRJv4rbgRRUBrrtFFKGJZqJCt2mLtd7yWYeOxH0n5Y4/JyTuQkEZh948O4stG1tPlufSAnDe0Y5AqKSuqTEnBDwd0EdI8CF6b6B/qsHCnhr9Scs396EZKK6TzRYlKZydHyUGtWE9utSoy@3@Ku761NJYtf20/RQVMpBUaMNEkIiaomLCPf3JEk@2nho3QIGcjsGlU2NH5zszFvMDM/TzCvMp5h3M1T3Fm/daqqu5GTLK/XGwvpLuratWqVav@rX9Fi2@9dxVcD2@bv7b7lzct1VWDv12MG5Pff1Nq5YV6TnUtP5NAqPnVYpajSL6k/6/U6xxzrkbwDQd1PUso5fGlPVAsq/AcXnii5D4yPjSvwUNiikvV4pXhQrjYjYpXp6vnxV4xV7g67Z0X4OQ3WiqOlvJLKXx4RqsozTGimT8dnWNNjUpd/d6NwlWdfKWadg1R7BpCX/bqw05/t7T/LiaNwwYAIjBt680Cdbllcw7WbPA98Xr@bUqLydIKHOtgg@TMsVdQHj7tLE@GOKbZIcyoV9K0mw3G/H/iOnM573ow6nOKrigD1lJ3nTtnzrgx5ViiQFlOO@cGnXWGE@ZJQTEkXydiRZ3Jy3YtD99JNwLiFCV5OkycJRLwKQSi2pfr9NwJPL/euAQSuFb2joup9XW@ZJZYLfBYigdTjvqQHSZy53iEAoR@BqxtQBW8cw/Y7cOh5uM9jwf5wjKqEfvJsIG8wztFpMD8W31h/yYuv04EEMLPyZ7L0yJOvfOijaT4DrJwAfHI4gd/qBngVimdMofGArbUVwyBs6U40wjVajLR97lbkFNoRX@6BZk8vz1ohs3vSnYmCeup9VsAWnKXctIGfrphsVSkWMYUM5kjpJj7JjUg6aLj0Z5Pw2qitvxul5AWWsyF5MAj@/fq@pds/cEp6jy3yEt65kF6JpbuSbogFebyaIEPM61FMyWSX8J89yoRZks/qKuoePPiUU83PNqShHkLX8sbeKN@rRNm3rBdKVxpE9ZjCZlIyucZvS8pT2JlLIPb9FNJ1/y9rHveYhnL@zZeP34d3UE@G89qW5MpLvV6ne4bWbRsCtgsQdRUSoqjv5ntZFBqH0w9ndAODnJ@HrYbxRDKUt7MODxmEhvrbxOe3mS8SU2jIV6MDwbWjDESoRLXucSEG7PDItXDyU8iIBgmGE2ZkbthCk904UkELHI9MdWKF@SDAU5Nmx7iRfhF3uGfGexx5Ey@5OzEOcF8LI0X7@Y4gXjSfZKYTab4bAJ3EfmoG/WVVSSsezINcfYksR@RAts6ffHBbkEM/sTOE9GJwswUD@huUzSlwwx5w76PdSES751/ZRedd3XaYw@6/liVcMyosxeWE3NwR9zZAJGdOBZNcD0YdKF15A3fLbtQ60AhyytQt4QQIyu751Rg2SP503jSDulUyFMHgHwLA5EwIbhut@FMBg/Y/i2mVkhcOiPPKfUmItCgMfN8WdzMfXUdiNaUTvvtKBLSczJ6QOlgUG/4nkN7tIB2P440tSXjW8vT4TeCCGO0pK05zl@vO41ft95Bn/syn3uej5DsRquDc97zF6GDFRHJJCznaBu7kn/hOBHdcEN0wxkATKtdLPQfiTf9G7/X850SrRicMaBNa@APb/ym5ziHvlUCAy5YGZpJ@GH3r4cNEe7QpqtOzAgv4SAt6jDiMPxifRZ1cYN1ZWkHSqtQ20xdfdNpgoDG46TVh3aYFRYIEyD0QKErf0REWXRVHCXWPWtceO9yBUEUUQNxTiK6CUuGXn/UaVDPsCTL6RIoUYOElfWaU5hQfY1uHc7B3iwE4B4TUsAgYFRJX8PB0UrzP4SD0g0zOva66ZkszX59His03P1hh2bfkMDcK1wsgjt18NH7SlVVD3aOPpUOy4qePxwefKxsl7fV5gnruKEo58C26v3BLs0uVpsuWvMD@pAoValkghOc0v6JKv/84bBcraqDQ1XZ@7BbIWgE/rC0f1QpV9Oqsr@1e7zN2neCoPYPjtRuZa9yRNmODtJcqynmhOXUwY7aKx9uvafX0mZlt3J0wjXuVI72URm0@iX1oXR4VNk63i0dqg/Hhx8OqmWFhjnblerWbqmyV972qH6qU5U/lvePVPV9aXd3qqEHn/bLh4qNBCKt3CwTlqVNOsKiJm7nduWwvHWEBoVPW0Q8QnA3raofylsVPJR/LlNzSocnaQ20Wv7rMWWiRLVd2iu9o8Y5qW9Qhfpl6/iwjPhHoET1eLN6VDk6PiqrdwcH20zravnwY2WrXC0oZ/egygQ7rpbTCpe1cdUEg6hF6fS8eVytMN0q@0e0Zhx/gL2DS538iQhDWJao6DYTGGYQaC0R6eDwBFBBB@6AtPr0vkzfD0FTplYJVIBFxdZRNBtVSEQ8ijZT7Zff7Vbelfe3ykg@AJhPlWrZpQ6rVJGhAoOME2IdqvSYW41@IrzkkZjVMZyb5u5UlR1V2v5YAeY6N3FAtaK5hcm29V7T3EPE3IgQpdOHzKB@FRWstB5@uvERgPKhRGa2jMZGTNo62C7TiqyDVSXChGNadV5NhVKKptFKYxPpNRaypulfXLdrnV6rDx9TW0wEH1dBO41bT1xc/nDmfOVyCS1f4QLJZK32sVSjg261VnPT31Myhsa3Smgx@NdyubqNiImPkzcEP2trQvf1GKE2nmlFJxvqQQGBnEL9Z2L6Vr/yXZXNNn1dDM77AGxER4GoTS6hSqGpkZ0dcUNFWCVLJvi9o9mBC6YMeK9Rg5wUlpGcqR/Qv95d@CKLQ@QDzc4i7spmcYhlNDq/@6YaqYRDIvA/HZGg0@IqvcD3f22nctHqcOb32v1@M@W6pgznHdE5sJ1yv1H8wm9PFc9Ml2dkWe2sw@gH5tzNWxirf9YkU7pfvCG3LIV/tRH/uAYbifkAqSlXxcJqLbRMPZPisEhKKx3aAu4V3MnY8@2Vfq58wmkut/yiMPX9vf0uYwv2gghUSwveKZc755/355KBBhjH4iCSdHSEjGw2UsbYm9jMt5TxEpn4ngFeqy99XteJJLSRva53o3ViNR52xlHsaR5@d1ja2zze2aGpE9i@eLXycrXg2LBbP6fl9wT1cKRXjjo2oHWc9mmcFBklW7Tx4ZESibcdsj8zcDaLjAiybjqNPyLOg7XbiFsyYSJDcwNc19KDiV7CBx0SigNwPHEMv84cmZoBUrGmumjNVX3MW/w67ZWYB7QxS3fCvTbGP8C2w98McdsgzUCaxTi@LnEunS543kvsGFNRPtxw4B5k8RKGjyWMm6UBi7rYfhbetfymeTvSi4GYMmK8crdzSULiyTQWythV9GRkf@A4I1oAzNHD6MvPmt/o8UQHuONwd/VgVBpViYw7tiTk1KEwWjf6VEM@3yhSFz17ZmtaV5DyuxopHntanGwDg0RGA6NyDqPCopoCXLBxRKarZAvYtwuu@iKciuAdgFPQHKvfiXNnNUdDKZj4IfrdRKVQAssGORGq3do6HJPlxMaxMOSMkemH6MHw/0SazIC/TidOgh5SKxIE8LsoyVCFVnR8ZaJ0bo2iIaLdCKkZ/XQSgrmPdsylbZjW3ozFv4ZIoHtnYj6ccNjDVmoGAcDkEGxEx681Sbus09HpbcLVxaEn6TWuBiml1wqzVDyAm1k9T/O2K210K3hxlSuypkiFu1RUvZWD2wWPejoyTR3l1dMgIeBcE/8ju8gCEDvgmUsvxWp1mrNyepSZeUCHWoosOE0bMYm2pfePau0WVSREZmzu15ovQygCvQF8HraTb//oKzHPjUdc5JVYHXEUPIQExzEZi48OWXfBhphdH3CeNlkYggtCRrdYILoCnUP1hdBU6ikbiqCS0OowjDOI6db1iLS8rN5a7FkyCQ612B/3JFi9L1Itk8OTAB8aw6i7vKf26hNCuft9zRYWyy5W@2nYLqIyEUvo8rgMpdHvD2nrWEe7Ccd0Z@J66pMWOvi94Hqo4xfSetYZaomE2fRTNdg2yemdlxmJ4c6oBZ0RvBWaHvMHN@nKh4WohCcZZ1ZVipjX8OiGETp2xkt5lVoPU9aJJhyWlIm4rlbV3Z3kEoLqkKE@U7AT2MMF22xyPdA72OF32x/@irUfW6Be02/ayKQRkCwLlE6q9DjGY2MkTR/0A5ZoUFdAAmIpkRdBmjVUpTX6pWYnbdeUCKNjInYpt@SP12OZ1FhLUUUh4@raiflWM9SZoNKyDg1qg4Xml1cYlVkHrvtHD2McLTSutlaJs56dUtZkE1F8araOeJJ50z6d4EkL@YtPA4we@gIdt96CAmHsWaFXfTjPMX6wKfjU8YfNqEyUdjLN@gDiNz769HvMi0Z0qMP@NeqjwJ/QCaCR7YyzDKOW@ql/2att9bv1dqffqdM5DTHcxzLj4XHCj@iw9rB/G/A9P5zQjGRqTsJniS8jYdjwbvWShUhormDkD1JRM4XRcFK6lDARLDmHEWB47SLz92A6Rpot82IlLOTE/U/ZHi/vFh4t@zw/q7Bo9AFAT3AbUxYU4kM6YsekiPNp4UGGi69liOB4oTKq7j5isRfD@DWRiNUwMYwNMg/MEqKNwMnsUYxPm@N0k2MQDhFoyd/2cS1NkOLP6TouuKVZ5A0sBdZU/lUuUlS0KGPEIcTD5HFyL7/8k7EnBH4A/fzzWdwyixF4imuZaEuBnFd0lFHChc0DOzxH80xMs1inTatQNwa0Np6GGk@ePEYNtvyhTZEOs/eAKzEiU3TwwdVxqRpNObWJi0VlQS24HLcDW5DSKJV7nGH9b9nP8uCHElckZ5iYtjTkVATpx0jVICrhLs8p89ooyhJT@dsjZnn5e3ttioDFWSZnkTtrUwmzc2EPlI6sr1Br9Yc0GSemqKdNPRaCUX@w8J3Ue3TumBmZbRatG677TUNgYbYiLZaLTSZtcYLHScGZxmeKaeIUY0sz4iEcX/nZsvk0EcfFGsZbsTb5Bh0eo1loN2UXFdvfTRn7WBRvYNFrFho7pBh3BCkt2O@nNWp47fEZRMOU41WNZ4wapozaRB4joKbIZKn0/RRi7tO4T9GjSZRDvU2iXbR/HiXqtJGcCXlqkmJBLkFPBG6H0ybNS4MWjC8QJk52uHaSshvOcXrCqrx85gJBhpEgALEr9jOhHEokuGFnTfER3w7QStVgLZTHTERPG1ELBxv03xKMo/Jr4Y62eKhNMvnzgkAaW0h0quBcX4Nk/M3p9bQ2ZigPSEFDfAYpbIsezE2X39@qH20L5SMIUpqTtaVvLo3GuGqJsKF/0aTaGHvgsCpdMjai4gOhxlMDjQU6pbS7vhxXsfvrDIXjYd2ghxEdIORzCj9LugTCea/mLLVRZNycIIuryS2jzVWZDSkSMpS8g/x6KMpWlw@uBMAXjKl8MU8QENaUsYdSgEPvRDkvhqjuIypYzGNY0keOihraec5IB1F1hhcrkRy5WTleR2FkZgKhjcXsPCEitGeZnSWEQgvdTFwiOV7Obk@YgzbEhveF4tQVulfiNLQ9JwSkR8bWziineZXOaQ7mxBcrbizR8jenvs5FUnPTqUQfi@FpJj@d@ioXS41Vu7wcLxorSfRwo7XGEokUbhRhOyv82B@7pkRDnlub0MghI7bL0PbZPRylbnFu8/4WqHV2yjZ7DAMv6hlujl81uWIlFpT96wHY1QKrDBC7/YdbayxTDSb6rgCOS2ecXVJyIOQdawJLPZqFk66JtGcDFJgzbb@lPh7t7MTCvl5MjKHRlT9cyeVyYOKLaPB7Y1sNUVKnn43nzrauu93s4Pan4ceLLM/9uNO@G/TXzAnapy6hQRF4/WFbboYADpQVuTPakRVn/etWK3oFAzSU6DzqNsmpoyEoXoA61ujl4xELgBikXmB/QQPRvl@UHX23ddloaihGDUWlYRJ8kzDaMyIPPrRgn201VQwME7OxZqJ1yy1ufMEKgptNuLM4fLH7JTRPTrz3u91@Wn3CTcGIFDB3P11gZydaICdZoGFk797rgOPRppV/0@lG/IqRJcrrAGcWJnPPhIkLj9j4h367PB6kEqefE7SsUJOX0MwlxKdOq0Q74epg8d8BVviQ0P6u3Ff1QarBdJrOTEu9HsHhE2H0PJ@eefaJZXFZJqZp9u3cIOpsdD0O1kBNd3kvYGLZc/dySx7JbombOBvnW6BhTmBonBBz5ftKwNXsz5sWb0at1vfNinwNgHTsH5oR5SaUH5sQWQfAI1APP6Inomj/JUPDemcqoIhscHBZx8N5BwVqKOA4TxvF325TpVJJzQ@WllSptEkPmYwqbZbUNj5sbqptet/E@7Pi8spKQebcbfcLfdw0H@/VJsFgCedS43K4Ta@UVoTfGKy10cXz2eJ8ujBfK65vFILsaWkTbv309M9//89//sd/ZUv65X/wsskvp59tJs/zsvONL/PP7gt4P90@X5i/OJ0fnC@0C@Cyf3HU8H5llKmH5qPe8MJJyioQ@cp2pOaczdFndFFlbvW7qg9/pdllTSUbQTapvwZycxTPscmGH/nuw4/ygo7w5tKB6aM8IZEkoBOI46l3Gj4M8Gi9IUoSLrADlfKiWzGCe4SDsRmsViWpI/HwnvXGh09LGEkBvri0YmU6vcDvQQJ@w3teaZ7j1Om3M6pp/s1@3gvam/2xWjxLqcWcWkyrxUSCf/Krr@mrO5/twDtXstFxIJFIU0qoWoCZoQo6vNHj8wPftTNFbseZ5yt7AMmEqeDM4gWXtqc/dpaRC9eCtjOHSzOViEhYyYQiyS/zvXvqli@U4z4Rc7XhjUJNn2K4sohGxfYvtkD1QAwBwpqvhCBrfaoSmj72SMZT1nzRfe3wbUIMGGQ9fLfD4x4faC2a72mb59hZCtccsfm8fMXaWBBnaEYbKVJ/iAArVOQ4mWNPwoXkgiNW3pFWcjPFCzvaPs18Yusw8UfGNl0K/ZuKMIFYc0cJN9/Tfi3akFvUKyrRseqVSFWJadtv5USKXF13R52Bdlfg2jGgvtja7mUkoUcZkMCRmP1rD0cYCwpMpKipbpHLsiaq2UfTZST0tGs6dbDrieYoQoTs5xSN7bupse1m2UvEsIPwACNlTfla9U430FFXhkzsdn14gdsB6y2@UG0kejOW5@Ga1CmM@y2LtMeQ2eQ8HM/UlORgWG9f1dMqud8/GtYnFVq2aOczangutRAhmIAEBp@uelbzDMLSIt0lTBHbFLYcwuUF3Ym@Hk36NmF9TtClZijosCsYBDF2Ykr6d7G@mqJjyNV/oBOiKD@YvK02Uk@xPPPC0khDSkTdZniYPRg6jqkhOnbswEk4gqodmYYXdKFrLLRXrPilmbyLGAG67oT2AtSuCKuvUT9Wp7bfq8cWp0HXMY7@2YKSdRHjma@iFGskx9x8mg9vvANWtI/8HI8CIWuTCWfkzKVSc2eBvs4tGV1HOMi3tcXP1lXHXkDHF5ixZ4g67nVkspxaocI7MDxVYct/gtDq1tuE3@S2PgErniVTb55k3dPPZ73zxdRZ7@7sd5cx0VOyWWUzKqmV2WbG0mOFVsZsOvZqrNICE2rwrBfPcNZT4sMSIQEhkk2dfs6e32UJobMk7p0/SwpBYl0GTLJfry8L8NkHaCbjWGSTzpy76JrOT73Ju4rWVv5FH8oHV34JC3OoZDE9nXOGLQLFfrq/XYvLSZB9tZx7sZx/QSehtj/ODP1rrLeZ4PrCH9NWIsBxlpaes99j3BAjxP04qBfo45jaKdeaiO9JoJ2U9BSqhznX41i2ojKe8ATlJypzuFS4uLg2Tx3KRxz404pYzuTlWFBiOhjhvhTWz6B/hXrqAea1ae8Q4UhYGYiNCItQM4BsLl95jENdM1wW2M/JU1uI3cpAqHuzychq0ev3Mnqz5noLBWyi4TXTfZV7lZseow@GaGyEzuvN1MITld948/If/33wW3KU3FjOfhrS7yj5W3L1VVIe6YHenpu3m@RGch3ZVu@Tkyydgenx5T/@l8pv/ERwkDJZp38bKwbW6iS5kSlykbvkxio95JeXqd7/@/vfqQ3zcmLDXazztbRixAqGIlv1HvMupasKWinH0oVwWmHHLMAQC0M6m9MLDKPGy69yLKZLaquKG19HvjL2KHqJZ8OsEZsKiSTD2FPQzkgKFFFBRkAaE4qWithuGLMNMG@Ipvrlqbca0AngF23OYau0phtPA5gMzcuxiDowJTXSeV4eNnJvEta8Yy1hbEoKZguJo52ea189L/w/)

I call the interpreter like this:

```python
import sys
from _110010000100110110010 import interpret
interpret(open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf8').read())
```

Handy table:

```
Command pointer:
 nil → 0:   ↕
 nil → 3:   ↨
   1 → nil: ↨
   3 → nil: ↨
   3 → 2:   ↑
   2 → 3:   ↑
   2 → 1:   ↓
   2 → 1:   1 (same as above)
   2 → 0:   0
 ---------------
   0 → 2:   ↕ (but also prints the data pointer)
 ---------------
 nil → 1:   ↨↑1
   1 → 0:   ↨↕
   1 → 3:   ↨↨
   3 → 0:   ↑0
```

The simple way to print a number is `↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↕↕`. But 300 `↑` takes 900 bytes, better use a loop.
To create a bf-like loop, we need to be able to switch command pointer from `0` to `nil`, but this can't be done without printing the data pointer.
So I use jump offset as a loop counter and the data pointer as an accumulator.

```
↨↑1      cmd_ptr = 1
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ jmp_offset = 8

↨        cmd_ptr = nil
21       jump forward (on the first run: data_ptr = 1)

*** loop ***
↨↨       cmd_ptr = nil
↑        data_ptr++
...

↨↨↑

2        filler
↨↑1      cmd_ptr = 1
↑↑↑      jmp_offset += 3
↨↨       cmd_ptr = 3
0        jump back (ip -= jmp_offset)
*** end loop ***

↑0       cmd_ptr = 0
↕        print data_ptr
```

The loop element is `↨↨↑`. The single `↨` switches the command pointer from `3` to `nil` after the jump, `↨↨` doesn't change the command pointer when it is `nil` (when
executing sequentially).

Code without comments:

```
↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕
```

The loop is executed like this:

```
    2<-------------+
+---1 break        |
|   ↨              |
|   ↨<----------+  |
|   ↑           |  |
|   ↨           |  |
|   ↨<-------+  |  |
|   ↑        |  |  |
|   ↨        |  |  |
|   ↨<----+  |  |  |
|   ↑     |  |  |  |
|   ↨     |  |  |  |
|   ↨<-+  |  |  |  |
|   ↑  |  |  |  |  |
|   2  |  |  |  |  |
|   ---+--+--+--+--+
+-->
```

After the loop the data pointer is `1+2+..+(n+1)`, where `n` is the number of `↨↨↑` elements. For `n=23` it is `300`.

`↨` borks exit code of Symbolic Brainfuck, it is fixed with `→`. The code size exceeded 14000, so I added another 10 `W`s to AlphaBeta code.

Comment: Congrats on 300!

Comment: This whole thing is so damn beautiful. I kinda want to put this on an NFT.

Answer (score 14):

## 8. Retina, 70 bytes

```
#v;7||"<+0+0+0+<;n4
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8
#|

#M`
print('1'if 1/2else'5')
#i2
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=I3Y7N3x8IjwrMCswKzArPDtuNAojPjNOLgojfFx3KgojOAojfAoKI01gCnByaW50KCcxJ2lmIDEvMmVsc2UnNScpCiNpMg&input=)

This program prints **1** in Python 3, **2** in V, **3** in Minkolang v0.15, **4** in ><>, **5** in Python 2, **6** in SMBF, and **7** in Japt.

**Explanation:**

```
#v;7||"<+0+0+0+<;n4     # replace every empty string with "#>3N."
#>3N.
#|\w*                   # replace words chars with "#8"
#8
#|                      # remove all "#". The "|" is something I could've golfed off.

#M`                     # match all places between characters (finds 8)
print('1'if 1/2else'5') # replace something that won't be found. noop
#i2
```

Comment: This is 2 bytes too long (50 + 20 is 70, 50 + 20% is 60).

Comment: @ais523 Fixed it.

Comment: Care to provide an explanation? If not, that's ok.

Comment: @MistahFiggins Sure. Added.

Answer (score 14):

## 33. [Incident](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Incident), 460 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::T):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12"; ␉
#[␉#vx#v0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111x0ex0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(23!@)
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9)or(13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21#|/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
#8␛dggi2␛␉` |1|6$//''25  #>say␉␉ 27#T222999/+/-/+23!@23!@"26
```

As usual, `␉` is a literal tab, `␛` is a literal ESC character.

### Rundown

This program prints **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVfbetu4Eb42XyE3WJIbkZFJkHTsxNZhnWSdfkl3s2ns3V7YTgyRkASbBLkAaMufD19ve9f7vkDfo7d9ir5IOgAlWbLlbHUgh@Rg5p8DZoZfHf1BH8v8cpSXCikqFcoEO6ciRK8v0S5hcjPZCC3LsIkyq1PGR0iNKWK8qhUaspxKKyUK9VE1FRNqAjlIUJI1bNawFEgvQcVZjqYfB8my0DcVFZWgcJSIU5ohWdGUDVlqhCM6UZRLVnJpZaWlF6bVPVXzK5cCD6czuLQiwsAtUWWwz1BfCFJVoM9y0D5gUKygEjHVkogSybQTYImkPDOWVnP3lIjwRcDonBFEwI5aGNmSCgVIQyMXjamgIJJo5SNBCuRdCKbAGu2IV@gjJQIdCEp90AIOpDIlFeBYUgnKSq1BaUNC4@hut7X3y9sWOLxZEZJKWY7YOPjLe4ugsIfcLx3492y7Y@19@BFduUeaBhQgDIJSCY/4qHeLJD46ovCfxAM8EjcWSLXAKznCZaUwSCZCAbw7KjhPwipfUIu69yKxkAQNVwaxAFuH9ALlhI9qMgILSw6sJE1ppaYBKTmYmDF@30JzM5iGK5Rjy929r9PAngZyQYciZ7Rx5dT5REciLYuC8CzIGaeIiFFdUPBJxgRNVX55XzswnN9Tbp9oliUAJ/YjEGY5BzlDJzStFRnkdB1djFk6RhcGHUdjck51Yon6gfFwa1G7KFAwnKvWYOL@08QK8fyWhvGoiECH9qEcCKgW1V@6YbJg8YYx0Oyqfb05ST7fQkhv7fmOnRsP3nivE0TQ32vwrkSSjbhmIXy@/SAaGW1yn0neUrCbJAMX6Y3E4MnBu1/0TvorbcoCOKnJqYXyA/eGDJZPN4p@MPOYRdNxiQKOWlMMnm3y@hRgYSlSQwQLm9n2Q3CXp91mHs0EnTb17X5io/5DPqOytY4Obft4HQ1JLiHevM5zuKh5qmuDR/0rSIyUShlCdpe1CnVVAHR2m/o3y4xqLMoLRG/8TmuVOhOQA7D5pxKq3E8M6lY5RO8WCqopvBNdb44su7pU45JvLGevrZ/soN/MhoFtU5YoL5uaCd6wF9cZ9/3M@Fmpw4yLGfUlCuPNsFqow1DlH64cMjk2hyXWOYaGN1nxxKyWxWBoDisYuM6je84xD4qSl41ycAfjBH8ypxC24yoEy1m/pP41hbiMaLC9gQeM4wEdPsb59vXrd4ZnOBiwx5jADbqlzc4r2EQ9WOWlAZHjB1URLfn5oBYqDzKs9Jn@528Z@PthNMbkUiqSns2JL5xe6MgEw0eDM12qL8xhdSBP6xy64h/ISIkAG0g@J1bL2kGfKCQjg8nANENAmuew98BlUB2W8qaBJmheZ3R2Xi3U@HC5uCLOCt0cKj1xPLLiXjdoFNY8g6wpSYabFs3oXfQaP9MJGZX8Ei9UmlAM/g9Ys4KN7nqyGteqbo66Ef9RnFil/9/ablPOaPPV63hvenqEH0BsPZanzRYRBLLybU7O8ECTX4ZArja1MUaw0YiK2fkxNipNkQkGZXkWNJOWxNBDYVatSErNVru7XJlDP0MfzmHY2v/w6/7HbyaT0QjSRN4cV4p7x1NoT1x9S5IpzZ9qvjiCyPXpDAb3mEBQ@qGFyXA21jp3TxEnMElALdf0rKd24Ao0ynFZ5xnMDTyDXP2VM9NF01I0M8w6GkBfNDXg3/@CWVqxPEcjqiQqmCQ5dGE9YcOgMi4vfjB6TXoFb17to2APtQyGIbK/D15E0l5H7qtPf/rtMDpuIdud2FOgkKUw1WQLgBtjkKfpj6aOTseuomkr2iZ6YcautOTn4D090WtaQtuCS9@I9qB2FNDNg32FNvUbAlUwtW3CGThhBIBBHTQZVuRO0PUUfF4B8qJ3V6QXmyD@kQ5qk2EwviYbPYMc5uNu31CCZmUHwaB85Yb96Ppakkvbvmn5C28SexMlCIQZmmlBNHBLv11o08taLQ2ZF0yNm2kIRqR0TARJzXvNbLLRCoeQwyiHdyP9amKSVmozkHZOM7U081dQ1Gr4EgXaNhjVKf7vP/6JRx09tiug/97Qn7H2BW49GIuNoDnQRZAwDUyrEiSTnuSB6w24gakdtPtnyjm9RB6EtiACxvQa6oTw12fvgkC8gdxL6Qqke62rvExJ7uKO8W/nRuLDkyO0dsSPMcC9xE9wiDtXnpv3LjHGqd/33HEvbm88a7dd/sxzeRD7/tOnOiY3ruy5X0I7tCfAFLi53wH/ey7pubzjkq7nZr3kmVkBl@22fwULbiUOr1xyg92nRxyvwx1B4WVWUs@Vvp6FojCMbwDcacm4i9cLUl15NrIniAykVu@ydltjCN0vGsAtPtpvA3Lw@T5G7lNDGpfjUdEx6d9a9vvXr875SbyF7a69hQfh77u2t4N2dg78HYTW4IN2vCTx950Of27Hz23L6W982NqNN8vr/trnZ0qpZ7ft9u3t7feW07vl77uf7DiBl7c1yzlcc84nznmUR8Ukis/iM6DYJDqdRONoHGdxHE8iOokG8IvKOIMjhW80AZJFw0k0injENVMJRDqJUiCGcBzpR0MQcgpfFkVatlZRRHlsPlHkJRvf7fqWc9I9ubaM1Z5Hz0nu2fHRJBkmtq8T29v2IUDxhu8HXqRvPPc/e7Hf7Xpbm36/v5XA45Z3dAW/G18fDj3/2L@ZXelzy3m@5b1sb0@/ve/8ntPoi1/4zrFjBuwkdq5xL8bJ896kt33Yddu77WAXPr1@uzs9/eD022EQhMfYcl4@yUYjljxZO0HX8fWWi3GrlWxCHevDXoeIJC@cgyRJtre3cRsHuK2N1X872fof)

For the languages that aren't supported by the above test driver:

- V can be tested [here on TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/v#NVFNT@MwED0nf4GL8YBqY6WecdNAQpLNeQ8cWG6lqKWfgZKwbFUZbchf79rAvjd@8@yxZmT5CIcZJZrnPNGPw98VFxnLsjuZMRY4sEwYI3/BdRNzinkI5egmqWjcdmXwcLHf7y96pfq@Pw@h6Juf@S0nw69ZEMIkgIOFA@7wxSI907NztcUni1vc0pKILK4sPrrAlpZOV45ona1xbXGDDTb@UuvMwuLCmbXTjS@tXZMnxxrR9/YjXnBHn0AUZnRayRBm@awLX9/qZi/E6jDfCU731qwNl/NmyUQq2zdBIykjgf4glg@CZJ6LZCzLMjGuPBD3f118SC8TIafy4//O5wHEibhS6TeLU1nA1zy6lDCF1WLbMkPQ6YK0iQtbpJP8TFUqqhyKUuXf6QeUahhFw6kO4epkudnU5iSYsY665EzrwcCMGYPyz/zd/Yi5hDtjTJqmWulIK/9Yv7hJjsd/), and outputs 2 as expected.
- Reng can be tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/), and outputs 19 as expected.
- Modular SNUSP can be tested [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html), and outputs 31 as expected.
- Incident currently doesn't have an online interpreter; I tested it locally. I've put in a request for it to be added to TIO, though.

### Explanation

I was always planning to add Incident once this challenge reached its 33rd language. You see, it takes a huge amount of code to do *anything* in Incident, and 33 is by far the simplest (and thus tersest) two-digit number to output. Even then, I only just came in under the length restriction.

#### Making the Incident code robust against changes to the polyglot

The main weird feature of Incident is that it's very hard to lex; as a quick summary, a token is anything that appears exactly 3 times in the input, and isn't a subset of another token, and doesn't overlap another token. It'll be much easier to understand this answer with syntax highlighting. Stack Exchange doesn't support colour in posts, and (unsurprisingly) doesn't support syntax highlighting for Incident, so I'll do it with a screenshot of a slightly older version (click for full size):

[image: The polyglot, with syntax highlighting for Incident]

The tokens are shown in bright, bold colours. Dim colours are for non-tokens; grey means that they don't occur 4 times, brown shows tokens that are invalid due to overlapping other tokens (and dark cyan shows the locations of the overlaps).

As you can see, the `#v` at the start of the program is a token (appearing three times), and as it follows the pattern `#v … #v#v` (appearing once and later twice), compiles into a forward jump, thus jumping over the start of the code. Likewise, `23!@` is a token, and follows the same pattern, and thus is a forward jump that jumps over the *end* of the code. As such, Incident won't execute anything but the Incident code in the middle of the program. The Incident code is interleaved with the Whirl code; the purpose of this is to reduce the chance that Incident tokens will appear in future added code and thus cause the Incident code to lex incorrectly. Each token in this code consists of a digit (`0` or `1`), followed by a lowercase letter (other than `a`, as the program already has a `0a`). So avoid that combination in future. (The reason I used this particular representation was that the Whirl code was already full of 0s and 1s that I could borrow.)

The most fragile part of this program, and something that's unavoidable in Incident, is the part that does the output; this is the token `0o` (seen underlined in the syntax highlighting; I chose the name `0o` as "output" starts with `o`). Incident identifies the token that produces output via checking for the centremost token in the entire program; this happens to hit an `0o` right now, but might not in the future, so you may have to add dummy tokens (i.e. something repeated three times that doesn't appear elsewhere in the program; three copies of the same token next to each other is a no-op in Incident) in order to bring it back to the centre. Hopefully this will at least be less obnoxious than dealing with the Hexagony.

#### Keeping the other languages working.

Given that this answer pretty much just adds a bunch of letters in the middle of the program, few languages minded.

One of the more awkward languages to deal with is Reng; there's naturally a `#` in its execution path. Luckily, this can be fixed easily by adding a (non-token) `x` on the sixth column; Reng treats this as a no-op, and Incident doesn't parse it as a token (as the program has a ton of `x`es already).

Hexagony was fairly benign; I just needed to add padding to line the `/+23!@` into the right place on the line. (Note that the second occurrence of `23!@` is for Incident, giving three copies of that token; you may well want to change the `23!@` token to something else if you move the Hexagony token earlier on the line, and the basic principle is just that the token in question should appear once at the end of the Incident line, twice very near the end of the program, and not appear anywhere else.)

Unfortunately, my first thought for the padding (`++++`) broke Retina. I changed it to `/+/-` instead, to ensure that it was valid within a regular expression (and didn't accidentally create an Incident token); Retina hardly runs the code at the end of the last line (it's already matched enough times by then so the value will be thrown away), but it *does* parse it.

The other language that gave some amount of trouble was Prelude, which produces when it sees `!` characters. Parentheses, on *any* line (not necessarily the same line as the `!` character), affect control flow in Prelude; thus the `!` characters on the last line are harmless. The `!` character at the end of the Incident code isn't, though, so I had to enclose the `23!@` there in parentheses; luckily, `0(…)` is a comment in Prelude, and there's a `0` naturally at the end of the Whirl program.

#### How the Incident code works

Here's the Incident-specific (plus interleaved Whirl) section of the code, with tokens bolded and whitespace and comments added:

```
0l 0m x 0                 # Run subroutine 0l, then jump to 0m
1k 1k                     # Jump target for backwards jump 1k
  0l                      # Entry and exit point for subroutine 0l
  0i x 0j x               # Run subroutine 0i, then jump to 0j
  0h 0h                   # Jump target for backwards jump 0h
    1d 1 1 1 x 0e x       # Run subroutine 1d, then jump to 0e
    0b x 0b               # Jump target for backwards jump 0b
      0o                  # Output a 0 bit, then run subroutine 0o
      1d                  # Entry and exit point for subroutine 0o
    0b                    # Jump back to jump target 0b
    0e 0e 0 0 x           # Jump target for forwards jump 0e
    1d                    # Run subroutine 1d
    0i                    # Entry and exit point for subroutine 0i
    0f x 0g               # Run subroutine 0f, then jump to 0g
    0n 0n 1 1 x           # Jump target for backwards jump 0n
      0o                  # Entry and exit point for subroutine 0o
    0n                    # Jump back to jump target 0n
    0c x 0c               # Jump target for backwards jump 0c
      0o                  # Output a 1 bit, then run subroutine 0o
      0f                  # Entry and exit point for subroutine 0g
    0c                    # Jump back to jump target 0n
    0g x 0g               # Jump target for forwards jump 0g
    0f                    # Run subroutine 0f
  0h                      # Jump back to jump target 0h
  0j 0j                   # Jump target for forwards jump 0j
  0i 0 0 0                # Run subroutine 0i
1k 1                      # Jump back to jump target 1k
0m x 0m                   # Jump target for forwards jump 0m
0l                        # Run subroutine 0l
```

First, note the random digits scattered around (these are bits of the Whirl code, which is slightly longer than the Incident code); we don't care about those. The random `x`s are to avoid parsing ambiguities (basically to prevent an overlap between a digit-letter token and a letter-digit token, we use `x`s to break up letter-digit tokens). Everything else is tokens, and those are the bits that are actually executed; all nontokens are NOPs.

The next thing to note is that this is almost entirely made out of jumps and procedure calls. An Incident procedure has its exit point at the same place its entry point is, and thus we use jumps to loop each of the procedures round into a cycle (i.e. we enter at one point, run forwards until we reach a jump, jump backwards, then run forwards until we reach the entry point again). Additionally, Incident cares about the order of the three uses of a token (it's how it assigns meaning to them), so there are also some extra jumps added simply to get the code into a sequence that will be interpreted with the meaning we want. We can straighten out the jumps to get the following pseudocode for the procedure definitions:

```
Main program: call 0l; call 0l.
          0l: call 0i; call 0i.
          0i: call 0f; call 0f; call 1d; call 1d.
          0f: call 0o (outputting a 1 bit as a side effect).
          1d: call 0o (outputting a 0 bit as a side effect).
          0o: a no-op.
```

Note that each Incident procedure has to be called from exactly two places in the program (due to the way the syntax works); it's easy to verify that that's true in the table above. (If the centremost token in the program is a procedure definition – `0o` in this case – the two calls output `0` bits and `1` bits respectively as side effects.)

It should be fairly easy at this point to see what the program outputs: the bit pattern `1100110011001100`. This is broken into bytes, taking the least significant bit first. So that's `33 33` in hexadecimal. And of course, hexadecimal `33` is ASCII `3`. The program could thus be made significantly simpler by exploiting the fact that `33` is the only 2-digit decimal number which consists of the same nybble repeated four times; and that let me fit it into the polyglot.

Comment: Wow! So glad I blew up the byte count now.

Answer (score 13):

## 19. [Reng](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/Reng), 152 bytes

```
#v`16 "<" 6/b0\ .q@#;n4"14""
#>3N9@15o|R"12"*^*ttt*~++%
#=|
print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62);# =#;print(17)
#       ~nJ<
#
#gg99ddi2` |1|1+6
```

I added another `#\n` so that retina would cooperate. Here's how it works:

`#` redefines `v` to push `0`, the default TOS. Then, it negates the TOS (`` ` ``), pushes 1 and 6, the character of `<`, pushes 6 again, and mirrors upwards with `/`, colliding with the other `` ` ``, which negates the 6. Then, it hits the `<`, pushes `J` (base 36 for 19), then outputs it as a `n`umber, finally terminating (`~`).

Escapes in between `2` and `` ` ``; and `#` and `g`.

1. [Try it online!—Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
2. [Try it online!—V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
3. [Try it online!—Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
4. [Try it online!—><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
5. [Try it online!—Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
6. [Try it online!—SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
7. [Ethproductions—Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYgIjwiIDYvYjBcIC5xQCM7bjQiMTQiIgojPjNOOUAxNW98UiIxMiIqXip0dHQqfisrJQojPXwKcHJpbnQoKDEvMmFuZCA5IG9yIDEzKS0oMGFuZCs0KV4xPDw2NT4+NjIpOyMgPSM7cHJpbnQoMTcpCiMgICAgICAgfm5KPAojCiMbZ2c5OWRkaTIbYCB8MXwxKzY=&input=)
8. [Try it online!—Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcovDgpHjSJd77ZJPyxLAO7L3OzscxpWpwIxhYVqBcnOPsT1mIjqzVZdNoJSqEGqvjp6tgCEebu1mGDKNpMmYcZxX1ECiQ1Pv@Aw)
9. [Try it online!—Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
10. [Try it online!—Befunge 93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
11. [Try it online!—Befunge 98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
12. [Try it online!—Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcovDgpHjSJd77ZJPyxLAO7L3OzscxpWpwIxhYVqBcnOPsT1mIjqzVZdNoJSqEGqvjp6tgCEebu1mGDKNpMmYcZxX1ECiQ1Pv@Aw)
13. [Try it online!—Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
14. [Try it online!—Turtléd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
15. [Try it online!—Haystack](https://tio.run/#0WHuh)
16. [Try it online!—Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#JcqxCoMwFEDRPb/g8sijYAytvqgpwSjOHTp0LqJFEJfYSugU/HVb8G4H7o7fnjRwy0Gnr@wJl0@LlSs4FZwzbPK7aalcwoOT4kmXeO@TTcoTwzqw9zo7H8eUqsGNYGBZgXJxjrM/ZSE6slaXTaOVqBBqrI6froIhHG3uZhkyjKbJmHGcVdRDoEBS7/sP)
17. [Try it online!—Julia](https://tio.run/#saHkk)
18. [Try it online!—Cardinal](https://tio.run/#pzRBP)
19. [JSFiddle—Reng](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

Answer (score 13):

## 24. [Thutu](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Thutu), 211 bytes

Fourth try. Hopefully the implementation is uncontroversially valid this time.

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::  (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#3]#echo 21#===2|/=1/24=x=9+/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6
```

␛ represents a literal ESC character, as usual.

As far as I know, there isn't a Thutu implementation that works in a browser yet. I used [the implementation in the Esoteric Files Archive](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/thutu/impl/), which is a compiler from Thutu to Perl (basically, compile the Thutu into Perl, then run the Perl). **Update**: Since I wrote that, the language has been added to TIO. So now you can:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB)

This program prints [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), **19** in Reng (test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**8** in  Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OjogICgyMilTIztuNCIxNCIKIz4zTjZAMTVvfD4gXip0dHQqfisrfn5+JQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKI3wKcHJpbnQoKGV2YWwoIjFceDJmMiIpYW5kIDkgb3IgMTMpLSgwYW5kKzQpXjE8PDY1Pj42MikjQDQ2KDgrOSs5KzkrOSs9ISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSMzXSNlY2hvIDIxIz09PTJ8Lz0xLzI0PXg9OSsvCiM4G2RnZ2kyG2AgfDF8Ng==&input=), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), [**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Lcy9bsIwFEDh3a/A4t6rSjZW694bY4iJo8wdOpSRH0ELBaQqaVGEGCy/elqp1Zm@5Qx43ZK3UIG3b4/fDagQdAhBSsWsFzhvHZADgXXx4huadKmWm3Hf9@NsTM75XmDM7XP1CsQwF7gUmMTX5dz2Sh2uu08FtLrxB4PetXtZyu4iqdAP6umXxukNVZWf1LVnjY3zambK/@Kdjvg3oqnGYo2H91MnmTDGyMlGsuziLZbGCpyN9sfjmUdbmSj5YfgB).

I had to pretty much redo the Hexagony part of the solution. It turns out to be easiest to run the Hexagony code on a diagonal, rather than horizontally:

```
        # v 1 6 / " < " 6
       / b . q @ " ( : : )
      : : : ( 2 2 ) S # ; n
     4 " 1 4 " # > 3 N 6 @ 1
    5 o | > ^ * t t t * ~ + +
   ~ ~ ~ % # = ~ n J < R " 1 2
  " ; # [ # | p r i n t ( ( e v
 a l ( " 1 \ x 2 f 2 " ) a n d 9
o r 1 3 ) - ( 0 a n d + 4 ) ^ 1 <
 < 6 5 > > 6 2 ) # @ 4 6 ( 8 + 9
  + 9 + 9 + 9 + = ! ) = # p r i
   n t ( 1 7 ) # 3 ] # e c h o
    2 1 # = = = 2 | / = 1 / 2
     4 = x = 9 + / # 8 ␛ d g
      g i 2 ␛ | 1 | 6 . . .
       . . . . . . . . . .
        . . . . . . . . .
```

The bold font doesn't show up that well for me, but nonetheless, I've boldened the route that the IP takes. There's only one IP used, this time, and it hardly runs any commands. The program starts by pushing some junk to the memory edge, then replacing its value with the sum of the memory edges to either side (which still have their initial value of 0), thus resetting memory to all-zeroes. Then we can just do `23!@` to print 23 and exit.

Thutu doesn't like blank lines. As such, I had to replace Retina's blank line (which matches anything) with `#|` (which also matches anything).

Thutu also cares a lot about slashes; they're the main syntactical element of the language. Luckily, `#` at the start of a line is a comment in Thutu, so we only have one line to worry about. However, `#` inside a line is not a comment, so the big long line is something of a concern. As such, I had to hide the slash from Thutu by placing it inside an `eval`. Luckily, both versions of Python, Perl, and Ruby all have an `eval`, and will all unescape `\x2F` into `/` inside a string delimited by `"`. Unfortunately, the use of `"` makes the code live in Pyth, and can easily cause syntax errors (e.g. `eval("1\x2F2")` is a syntax error), but we can use a lowercase `\x2f` and Pyth will be OK with that, at least syntax-wise (it's in a part of the code that never runs, so we don't have to worry about what it actually does).

Thutu interprets most of the big long line (up to the first slash) as a regular expression. As such, the Prelude code was causing problems, as `+++` is too much quantification. However, it was fairly easy to fix that by re-associating the uses of `+`.

So how does the Thutu work? Most of the code is a comment, with only one line of code. Thutu's kind-of like Retina; it works by repeatedly regexing a working space. Initially, the input is `=1`. We first check to see if it matches the regex `print(( … ===2|` (it does, because most (all)? regexes ending with `|` will match anything). Then we replace one occurrence of `=1` with `24=x=9+`. At the end of each cycle, the Thutu implementation will output everything before `=x` (i.e. `24`), exit (due to the presence of `=9`), and keep the `+` (which we don't care about) for the next cycle (which doesn't exist).

In terms of places where code can be added, the main offender is Hexagony, which is *incredibly* fragile in the current case. As such, I suspect that the last line is currently the easiest place to add code if you don't want to redo a large amount of work. The `6` at the end is used for SMBF, but the `|1|` is used only by Retina, which can cope with any other regex there that's matched a lot of times, and Vim; a few 2D languages will pass over the line but will consider most characters fairly harmless. Before the first ESC is touched even less, with only Retina caring (although if you go too far right, you'll affect some 2D languages, like before). Note that there's a limit to how long the code there can be, because if the Hexagony side length gets thrown off, everything will break.

If you're willing to redo the Hexagony, the long line is still a good place to add code, although slightly worse than before. The `===2` is purely Hexagony, and will hardly be seen by other languages (although Thutu wants it to be a valid regexp, Prelude doesn't want parentheses or exclamation marks, SMBF doesn't want periods or mismatched brackets). Earlier in the line (the `#@`) is also a safe place to add code so long as you're careful with Thutu and SMBF, and redo the Hexagony; you may need to add a `0` or two at the end of your code to prevent it confusing the Prelude code later.

Finally, if you're prepared to dodge the 2D languages, the `#|` line is pretty much entirely free, with only Retina and the occasional wild two-dimensional instruction pointer causing problems.

Answer (score 13):

## 32. [Whirl](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119175313/http://www.bigzaphod.org/whirl/), 388 bytes

### Program

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::T):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12"; ␉
#[␉00011000001111000010000010000011000000000000000001100011111100
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9)or(13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21#|/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
#8␛dggi2␛␉` |1|6$//''25  #>say␉␉ 27#T222999+/+23!@"26
```

As usual, `␛` is a literal ESC character and `␉` is a literal tab.

### Rundown

This program prints **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

- [Whirl intrepeter](https://tio.run/nexus/whirl#XVBNT8JAED23f4HLsoPpLpuynaEstLS1Zw8elBsfKQoiiSmKDdFY@texQL34ZjJv3ptJJpkTHDI0mkfc6KfeR8pFyMJwIkPGrBosFETyEca5z9HnNiT9e5PiYFcm1qJbFEW3Uqqqqhsb4iq/ix44Eh8zy4ap5Xkeoudd6No0qvG8/7hYiNdtG7IoK@33/TYvhFgflm@C4@yLXojLZb5iIpC7vcC@lK7wzoYvFwJlFAkzkEliqB47YvZT51Gey1TIuTz@qTM74BsxUkETcVvGcL2HQwlzWD@/7hghlDpGTX78FQfTqKNS5aY14kRFDd1Conqu25trG0at1WazpZaVsRJL09HacWjAGCSfy@/6oTSECREFQaC0on475WROp18)
- [Polyglot Test Driver](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVfLets2Fl6br5DNKcVGZGQSIh07sXWpk9SZL5k2zcRuZ2E7NkRCEmISZAHSlj9fvtnOrvu@wLzHbOcp5kUyB6AkS7bcDm0RIHiA85/74deGvuBjnl6O0ryEkqkSEsnPmQzg9SXsUq42o43AsgyZzJMq5mIE5ZgBF0VVwpCnTFkxLaEPxfSYQE@gAZLRpCazhrkEvQWysxSmVwNUnunFkslCMrwrEIwloAoW8yGPzeHAJiUTiudCWUlu6Y1xcY/V/MlhSCPYDC4rqDRwcygM9hnqC0mLAvlZDdhHDCXPmAJeNhUwqrhWAm5RTCRG0mKunhyoWAQM55wCRTkqac5WTJaINDDnwphJhkdSzXwkaQbuheQlSqMV8Qo@MirhQDLmIRdUIFMxLRDHEktklmsOpRYkMIrudpt7P71tosLrHQEtSqshNw7@9t6iEPTAOengr2fbHWvvw/dw5RzpOaLAw9AohXSpB71bUOToiOFvEg7ISN5YeKqFWkmB5EVJ8GQqS4R3N/PPo6BIF9hC954lFpygpkrQFijrkF1ASsWooiOUMBdISuOYFeXUILlAERMu7ktoFv2puQI1tpzd@zwN7KkhF3iU9IzVqpwqn2pLxHmWUZH4KRcMqBxVGUOdJFyyuEwv73NHgvN7zO1TTbIE4NR@BMLM59Bn2ITFVUkHKVuHizGPx3Bh0AkY03OmHUtWD4THpUXuMgN/OGetwYT9p5EVkPmShvHoEb427cNz0KD6qP7SgvGCxQUjoImqfR2cNJ2HEOjQnkfsXHjUxnvtIJL9WqF2FSg@EpqEinn4oTUSVvs@V6JZYjQpjirSgcTxzcG7n3Qk/Z3VaQGVVPvUQvrBtSHH7dNA0S9mGrNYPM7BF9CcYnBt49dfEBZRMjYTfyGYbS9AdblabebV7KAvdX6779jQf0hnWDbX4dC2j9dhSFOF9hZVmuJDJWKdG1zmXaFjxEypAL07r8pAZwVEZ7eYd7NMWI5lfgHsxus0V7EzBjlAmX/IMcv9wDFv5UN4t5BQTeKd6HxzZNnFZTnOxcay99r6zQ78YgIGwybPIc3rnInasBf3GfX9yMVZrs1MstnspB2Em0GxkIcxyz/cOeRqbG5LpHMMNW204o3ZrbLB0NxWEAjtR/eUY15kuchr5qgOLij5ZIYAw3EVgmWvX2L/mqFdRszf3iADLsiADR@jfPv69TtDMxwM@GNEqAZd0mbjCjJZDVZpaUDV@EFWhCU9H1SyTP2ElHpk//lHgvp@aI0xvVQljc/mkxPBLrRl/OGjxplu1Q/mttqQX6oUq@KfnBFTiTLQdD5ZfdYOfGLojBw7A1MMEWmaYuyhyjA7LPlNDU2ytErYbFx9qNHhcnIFwTNdHArdcTyy4141qBlWIkGvyWlC6hLN2Z31aj2zCR3l4pIsZJpADv4PWLOEDXc1uRxXZVXfdSH@MzvxQv/@KNymlO3NV6/DvenwCD2C2HrMT@sQkRS98m1Kz8hAT0@GOF0tai2M5KMRk7PxMTKmTJLxB3l@5tedliJYQ7FXLWjMTKjdPa70oR@xDqfYbO1/@Hn/4x85k0monyqx2Dio9WnnhGtcAiZsLDwqmDWjjbu3ICjWf8zAej6rhB18Qo5qnFdpgtVeJOhhPwtual@cy7rzWIcBVjMTuf/@F3bAJU9TGLFSQcYVTbF26r4Y24txfvGd4Wucwn/zah/8PWgaDEOwv/VftJW9Ds6rT3/55bB93ATbmdhToOhb2IskC4BrYcDV848m@02bpawuBlomdmGapTgX59gr6T5czxUWG3z0zNEuRnyGNdjfL2FT9/WsxF5rE0ekxMKN7TVyMqTgTOB6Cj4tEHnWu0uti6WLfM8GlfELbDqjjZ5Bjl1tt29mkiV5B7C9vXKCfvv6WtFL275pegv9/96klBTNjCUwoxq4pb8JtOh5VS61hhe8HNc9DDY28ZhKGpuvkVk/ohkO0fMgxS8a/UFhXE1pMUArp@416q7Jz6py@BJ8LRs22Iz897ffyaijm@0S5/@s55@J1gVpPmhmzUFzoIsgsYZPcwk6k@6/keoNqoGXO7D7VyYEuwQXTZtRic11hdEtvfXZFxxO3qDvxWwF0r3mVZrHNHVIx@i3c6PI4ekRrB2JY4JwL8kTEpDOleukvUtCSOz1XWfcC1sbz1otRzxzHeGHnvf0qbbJjaN6zklgB/YEiXwn9Tqof9ehPUd0HNp1naQXPTM78LHV8q5ww60iwZVDb4jz9EiQdVyRDD9BFXMd5ekOph0E4Q2C@5Jz4ZD1jBZXrg32BOhAafYOb7U0hsA50QBuydF@C5GjzvcJOE/N1KicjLKOcf/mst6/fm2cn4ZbxO7aW2QQ/Lpruzuws3Pg7QCs4QU7bhR5@42OeG6Hz22r0d/4sLUbbubX/bXPz8qyfHbbat3e3n5rNXq34n33kx1G@Mm1ZjUO19rtdhi222aoJ9On6Vr7/mWWwrCmthqn3dNry4B2XXZOU9cOjybRMLI97Zfutof6DTc8z3fbeuG599kNvW7X3dr0@v2tCF833aMr/L/x9O3Q9Y69m9mTHpuN51vuy9b29K/3jddr1PzCF17juGG62ihsXJNeSKLnvUlv@7DrtHZb/i5evX6rOx2@a/Rbge8Hx8RqvHySjEY8erJ2Ctfh9ZZDSLMZbWIa6mOookKjF42DKIq2t7dbpBVtfLNrR1v/Aw)
- [V/Vim interpreter](https://tio.run/nexus/v#NVBNT8JAED23f4HLsoPpDpuy7lAWWnZrzx48KDc@UhREElMUG4Kx9K9jifjezLzMe4dJ5gyHXBvFLTfqufeZcZGwJJlgwpjXgCWCCJ9gXERcR9yHtP9gMj3YVam36JZl2a2lrOv6xgdXF/f2kWviY@b5MG06t3nlf@y3RSnE@rB8F1zPjvRKHJfFiokYd3uh@4ihuL0YES6ERmuFGWCaGmriQMx@mjrhZUwFzvH0v100gMiIkYyvdG108HdPDxHmsH552zHSUCmnFUXu6OKp7chMhlkDl0p7lTtIZS8Me3Plw6i12my21PJyVunKdJQKAhowBunX8rt5CQ1hQkRxHEslqd/OOJnz@Rc)
- [Reng interpreter](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)
- [Modular SNUSP interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html)

### Explanation

First off, thanks @ais523 for the Polyglot Test Driver! It helped testing tremendously. I'll need help updating it for this solution.

Whirl is, well, maybe you should look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119115023/http://www.bigzaphod.org/whirl/Whirl-1.01.swf) flash representation first.

Whirl only reads `1`'s and `0`'s and the only performs operations when it reads 2 consecutive `0`'s. So this is a really easy one to fit in and is unlikely to break on future additions. `1`'s just spin the dials and singleton `0`'s switch between the dial being controlled.

I debated with myself about going with this solution because it's so byte heavy, but ultimately decided that it would be worked in eventually, since it can fit in so easily, and #32 is the best place for it since round numbers are much easier. In code we're adding up to 2 then multiplying by 2 until we hit the magic number.

The long binary looking string could be moved elsewhere if needed in the future, but you may need to rework the solution using the flash program if you lose track of where the dials are pointing, which is very easy to do. Keep in mind that there are 4 `1`'s in code prior to the Whirl string, which are integral to the correct output. Everything after this irrelevant dial spinning, like a DJ that forgot to power the turntables.

Comment: I was actually considering Whirl for 31, but that language is a pain to write in (and I wasn't aware of the Flash program), and I also hadn't cottoned on to the fact that 32 would be easier. So you were way ahead of me on this one. (Also, thanks for setting up #33!)

Answer (score 13):

## 47. [Lily](http://fascinatedbox.github.io/lily/), 938 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)" 3//v\D(@;'[af2.q]GkGGZ'#)"14";n4
#/*` "[!PPP(22)SP(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@ ␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{#z}
#=<xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][PLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDO]>+.---.>][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++Lnd
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[kGkGx@O6O4/0l0v01k1k(0l0i0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100^_)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"__*
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#ssseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp/*/
#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(   )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*'``
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<.>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\
#ss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#ss*///^_^_Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpJd9tIkj43/kJd0iDLBEgC4CLJCwlasi3XqDZrLNn1nklaAsEkCQtbYZEoydKb68ybQ9/7Msf@H32dX9F/pOaLTHDR5qo69HtDP4KJzMiIyIjI2OTfSvRh@5F/PvWjjGU8zdg48U55YrKX52zb8dLNVltRBFQSjXPXC6csm3HmhXGesYnn81RxnYz1WFxgMWnASizhzliCKZMoYbSFBSc@85gbx2zkOzPTZb4nYNMooPWMJ3HC8UxZyPmYpTF3vYnnCjqMzzMepl4Upibz3BN25vk@G3MfG1bE3TqQsTxdm5KkTGUcKQwfN77F6vKtzAET8sVxeewk4rgRi8XZF6c@S5w4BpNKiR2A8cwLeMq8rJIy7qQeyRBbUh6OhaTipXQj5oTrp2SnnsMc8JsnAnfKkwzHMwVeNuMJB0qHiE8TJ2DaWeJlEAEJcoftcydhhwnnOqhAATx1nRh83CAJYhFRyOggplBUt1vZffumAoXJHaYTZ0opaR/@@/eKw0yblY86@Nqq2lF2f37NLssDGoMLIINS40RzdGZfs9QaDDi@8@bImiZXCrAqkIrPrCjOLGB2kgzsrUbGacuM/TWyrHtLE2tGJKHG0AXbC9mHujiXmycJBxcrkTonOLIfhVNIE0dN8pCkEbKtBhTgRuE4rTN@CplFodRQdCbkezjzoLKUFOKMIB7HJcnLCyDEiSsAyyvkuaCbRn4u4LAzzcj8IBNsJYx7E/aBTRzPpy1YJ1SS64SnuZ/Rnjwck94DL@Rjky3YcKMxAQXRKcg5QComcGeCtZsmmAIw1BCJo9LSP//6t/F0Cjw7rhsl48JYP7Bx5OYBGHYEsw4Mkcw1Ch1fsAW4OlGX20Hg1PG9sZMR@fC8ICGYEFTPotwfswgEkzMPF2vmnOIyTibczbg08SjPwGOdBc6J9A@etFscPHBGUKwgIGiLYxts@xW05HJpMEaQZ5OnzIh3WSW1PmkvnmsvHg04eNNNvVq2rGkH1mZWxRTeKl8znA87K32S9Rx6Ed0iP57l8BlYCdMY3iQhYboOjpOSU8ng8@psJAQtPBEMXVzRM15JOBvhXi8OJmxE2gDtN@jeFhhWOl3A3TQxPl6zMFgnjCxL7zgJPzoDYcEbOU7YdEjEnakDUllxoB15IElRzNw82kkISydsI86eGiMP2iE7gKsplLF2RoC3WxIG2KT21i5F4JwDiytd9EqTzJtAyQHsNjlnLqfLgFvBpZ8jIrkwjNSDHUUT1jBam5u/o/wssXaMj5ZjXFhf1TEd/paad9iEnzHfCae5M4UhRyG2OK7L46y4QThJmuGO3HaDYtIofLqZzpTy9m3awrcV3n6NBnkfqb3CQztk9hBUAFEbPm45c5KpuIls7CW4L/75beoAOL1FXD0mkBsMHKsPsLAITDAyPudunuG6wZDPZp47g@0Sd6G8sNI73iaPqXXqcDnGZEmamGn2HrcU01pOERsPojBIo3fxwOsTqt6NCaH89Ql5QETeA4r6cFWLMCtuwTIVWJ4dwviegkjCf80hXNieNw0JxAmXIXrNi3lpWIFb91IPEqJgS3Z5uPeWfPcvXOYbkJGMO@uON0L2ge1FMKWFhcAU7s4iZoSsUvCgqSL2fQZbVpq4YmCsBXxVNyEtjaQmlhaIPssc6nbwY727cIJkpc76qjqsI974KdQd5r6PlzwU10Hj@iXswuVpasK4cQdNyhzAnVrj@tVNwGyWRGeMX@mdyn3k/qRCXuUjb/7/UCMu8SWfONWaGsTUH9HDHcB/sSLu0IMq9kJEGfjfCxEOQnJveZD7TiYzAjfKIeelOhAaHLshNXgIGf2ILIn96FHwmiCnWuXaIj2fU1Y5UNT4PJtFYfum@1FXKy2Z3n2wAkQjMz6/P/Cq66jEhp@88CQi3qxgMTpqmM3NGyhQHtzdOfHSmXjcAL3D1t0VsTsNRhPxuAcgJFO8ZfFiIYjCSBKHhLzQsd6JHxMu9j4ObnqyG@Rfcuh4yo1nbWvkhdaITx6CfPPy5Z6AmYxG3kNAEAMVQIvfe8CSfHSflJDAzO5EOnZDzod5kvnG2Mrol//vf4wh77vamDnnKVLek@XgKORnpBlj8qByiq30Ih73K/Jz7qMc@h0crkNpruMvB/fjes7ecVg7EpJQVEHg1PdxkSEyOJi75oyb4Odjvvi9H6mQ4c2AKXeHXmDAlrfMhlAgXikJoFTsISy3or5EQ9VB4kfO2JL1msdXGpWy53NnGoXn1lpIMZPRH2B1EZjZqkDLZnmWyydVZb@nOy@m79euYAHZ2Nx52dwtfh6ABxNbD9muvDYJvIvxxndOrBENjyYY3n9UeZjEm6IEXPw@BPbLQey43DpL6edes/kJ6ZSPwvrg5/cH@1@1H4EQeVbiy@e96PZCF0EtzH4fE07pi8efMTxhB67jw/ra0vaoL2Ksicm7JVjfGZ1TIT/78zZEVKe1GjOiVbWyarvE8cObXPf@TbIxI/a5EepJ/ntRB6HDC3Dc1nht@KBNeJGxqolSaUgTKgLv8T3OqcMM13dSmEZWSJefQhvi8TVTpQjhks2sRl8z1FtMLerSh0qb1c7YcyNE71iomV58vDwU1G5nDys01HATj9VWeiMAmSq8Ey2UZU2T1ovOD@a8pKj002UzrbRaZaETiEqPxosspCPLyXQmeggo@8Zwiu9DT2SBbpTIokhW3iIA/ePv46K1MuWojQMvRcIzDakZiMpnFp29kHQL6juxA2kKFLiFvkwTjVc7LD3zMncmGyrIq96/OXxaVMNFXxIv@@QM15iQx8bSBCw4GReFm2RmHHF5gwu6y12LM0EfeRCyM2@czZB6HXgocEW1vagAwUlCYCi7I/IAdbbHxpzcg8hyP@dIzPwoOhHJNXHyj7/LHgAWgQxcY7wgL5pSaxQZrLEpCm9XZoELJBc8iQoQjWQMq8ohkXP4Hy7ndebOHNGcSExmLEpzIiPL81c7B8xAbU4tVarUO95EK@@8@@5DvzG0r1lgIVWwKM8VclO/NZ40U7XOFiCdK47MeH25geXVaoWp5blaHIvad6JbtbQpaW9Mo7FQ16LUDkTnT5gdPxOltuinhHRpqKWGaiLN8KoL1LIFZ5c15BgBCgfjIGOb1HfmEAlGslfIqJMLimILK8/ZFzYjYzFc1txs4E1KxKdWRWCvUrv1bNp6zUe5iEGnLbPVtsV5ykd2tydGCR9H1MzqfxqMh1a6EMtgMP@20ZqT3B5bdGt2f359WTZ7jS9fUuecqepVpSMKDvW5ysqX@3v7uweHO4fvDyDDK72Q3n7RoRXdRqfoPsOQ83RxKwvhUaNaNAtEs5k2C9xluVViQ@RKPHEBFlcZFNYKDlOaoqY5tZqur/XNd@fwXbBY6l@K/qOy4CwqumsLFeKGzmQZidpyaYTpsiKkI0zoCvlQApU8ImynpAVGGjfZjp/C5Mdj6HB0nnFZAckicFkJqiVWdszlKepMVQg2te92WaDhM4Qq91huLgs4gTm9r1E54NY///o32ZwcZBj/ZzGeYPzfcvzJIind7WZJHpeiIbF82NtnKfyKPHjgzNfOJMs7GHeYowoOIMFTIRACl8yuzrvCo/U/QJ5QAoRJJkpWKejxZKjNsix@blnkiKeRPzFFMs/n0AOM2kT@av2aU68YN8na2tzaaCJX5MbpAqFoa0wps5QIdf05U5ly6sX28chl3W6XqaiefW5vdaQgrbLzqa0eLxktA1aRTrvPsAdbVjuw1iu2aWWn1tRpK7NtVmlW2LADfyz1giutiQFAdJoOC3mo8BlRISoqzPk8Y7Dm5HwRixAJUOQFJCfxF4MFIgOIJG5dVe7YLvjFikgfvRtx0lxXg/oLgYlk87l6n@kwWMj/3GM5Icb/Jcf9QcO4Ht7X7V7azs7dprZ2uyVNZ2HbB2FEFcUb8Mq0ltVqW80tfe2eqAUqcEu34gtQ4h7gXrnc@xzF6c6r3b3v3@4f3GnKCsjKbbAKq/S6tYFh1vvD5aByj80v8@PD6AQcf6U7aWQE4V2s9ym9Yvdan3IxhaiidW@wqssW6tqZF8RhuMVMuamC6oqSq9wppNbZWGS2S6LrO@8eduH3YDhFJQdbpD@FUeMMgcEDJ9s/8DDk50zDtQocWKuTI/9N9Prib7H1Zfd87ST/VhSGt41tt3LpR7hSZasjQlDnCnZ1PGCDbDAZhGRcnXPrG8u0Opda2bfPLfgDvaeVZ3az1q7WauWwqpVDuhGPH1Pkuirjwh2ZqqnOAWSUfb0DN48LapfDTtnpauWx3aqKHXhFYLjEhuvUMi/LzpVVfgz7rmMm4eRGuFZOdcpTGqbZvAJ/nyMvLFv1wIkvNZWpc/ojBJEve7Ua8WCWj4iBa2twUAPnuC4HloiXncLPWtOgI9xR5aaV/vZbqbnFmKpdtdqPtnWVtS3rdPBa2@5U@s6kZf46/O7ku@8@Vkq62txQO@GGUrKqx0ztP9rf39daLf1gX@s9YU@q9c7W02od25r1bfYXfNivSqn3F@iv1956tI3BcfdYKXWHtW7f7BnDXl8pXZYurpSS3Z2/q9Gn/7pXk58f8e0aw/7@j7s7B7v1VtcotV6/rbcO3r8sNfGy2Vqs0Awtt7H@bnfn9dv3h3UMv9v7sPt@//XbYa9mGoZh9oYg927@be/6@rrGatfVLMuq5lwpve7N31tGl2iGY4AIcGOgY8cXpdQv9U9w/vn22623G1bDb5w2mifNEw0jr/F53pg1Zs1xs9mcN/j7xmjeGDWi5hhPjn@NAEOvMZk3po2wERJQhIE7b7gYTPCc0tIESD7jn9doEO7G6RxE/Kb4NBqfjvSNLe1p7Vnxz36kUybxRRG61JjGT5EgaGpzMG9NWqqO8Kg902F3zbauG1qDwuWG/qnZ7Wpbm3qvp221dCxXtEvtsnml06OvNfShfoXRgKYqpasS3bCQbWzqcPtc/2LZTau1Yc@75dp2zdjGx@7VusXPi9JYyNi0lKOj1zuHO0dHdrNkWUrJHJhqs6UeHVWJ5Q7lnZHPTR9@tv1MUfEhMHvEpyBGG9I05Sgs@L7Dc87P8vyMLz@vUOx8/gw/E8dWFbBjPqHE9oKl8CnRpOJWjOYLtf0USWD7iaqU4HeoW9Wlvl5kznoK9WQ1XARdbNf049LxoFK1Lqlk0y6Y3rmyqpXjY6VcIcgK8WO0o42oVC6XYbZmT22rb03Fpv@6QHwT@@IApS/RZvM6/L5Teh5X2huVAR3k6Tfj6dRrfcOOvzS/bJUtq1JpbTJml6Temk/0Uq/1xEQCWxoWcxuYG5aE02o1gaIKj/Pp6NPRx1ar9ezZM7W19ZtlfS0@YHXpKiccXiQP7vOVO4n3k0M5Yrj0lxj8lMM1L8XGSG6@NyLB3ZiTslyfEv97AnMK8SWETANUdm5dJK6sSg29/lBnlyIr9iZMo1WEy6bMzmURkuVJyBodRQJRW6izHIIKqZnZBECT5Bo1z252mNclZPiFRy0o0Gexo2bT0OehJrjwhnpnCbPkpIfda7ys7a/VJPiVZEuexw3G8thybfkK9gKqqF2t2K3fAkBBApjKoFEpjvlHjoGory0x1NmfPsat/Qge@uJMgoXVYjG/UsWVUs3qQUehY1fjjvKD5uqXFNQ618Hjx@6nuB8MO3pgZ/RbqwWdK@VE8yRINbMD22h2YjDbyfq1mje0A/0HLRbMB3YDwKBNmFP9cqnp0C7Uler1i35oXIfD@pt@WGsO63m9@tG@qDt2oz7HF2Kr@/VfIbyFKLXMvqiFHaeLL8XXG5KI7bTmdG5M0ZYTzbcv@s7QbugdHxtrtTc4DPhM@36tNtRB3Mfi3Y0d//Fjp@b35h3fMHSC@tR@8aafYTCs2fT@XHO68xcX/Rz7n2v4tUHG18E89t3UAfCBvw5kLNW3Yl3yOCf25mAvsO3qxxfVj1X70aOL/twIhnUp/ueNleKJ@Tkxv24jWvXjumEJkYgCW1O/9Z5/a1ZTptZhfRByPV7bKTmsfsRKvLoNV/8H)

[VIP score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .009034 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 999 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/). I’m not positive this doesn’t have an error, if someone could verify…?

Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).

Cubix’s cube shape viewed [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)

Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.

### VIP

I’m happy to announce that with the addition of Lily today, we officially have the lowest VIP score of all time. And so, I do hereby proclaim that this polyglot, at the time of writing, to be unequivocally the greatest polyglot of all time. Congratulations to all contributors.

Because we’ve finally achieved this self-imposed goal, and because I ended up touching code for damn near all the languages this round, I’ve added a small code snippet from each language along with the code change description.  The purpose of these is to provide a place to search for code snippets from the polyglot for research starting point.

For example, if you want to make a change to this `8+9+9+9+9+` you could search for this string, to find that it’s part of Prelude’s code. Then, you may wish to read over the original prelude answer, look at some prelude code changes that have been made, or review the Prelude documentation for alternative solutions.

### State of the Test Driver

I copied @SnoringFrog’s Alphuck Transpiler into the Test Driver for viewing the Alphuck code’s in the BrainF*** character set. I found it much easier to debug this way, and I suspect others would as well.

I also added titles to the Extra Information outputs since Alphick’s output is easy to confuse with BF if you’re not familiar with the Bash script.

### Lily

> `]#print(47)#`

Nim, we know from this polyglot, uses `#[` and `]#` for block comments and according to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101189/63156) tip for creating polyglots, Lily uses the same syntax for block comments. So, I wondered if I could find a truthy/falsey abuse to create different outputs, but alas I could not.

Then while browsing Rosettscode.org for unused block comment structures, I came to [this](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Comments#Nim) post about Nim, and realized it was wrong in its assertion that Nim only has single-line comments. Then I checked [Lily’s post](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Comments#Lily) and it too failed to mention block comments. (Sadly, I did not have permission to edit the posts.)

Then I went ahead and looked at Nim and Lily’s documentation, just to make sure I wasn’t crazy and I saw an exploitable difference. Nim allows nested comments.

I sat on this knowledge for months, thinking it would be my final addition to the polyglot because it was virtually guaranteed to be available at any time considering its block comment structure was already included, and because it was so under documented.

Over the months, it occurred to me that abusing nested block comments is not a trick that’s not documented in the Tips for Creating Polyglot thread, so I added it. My explanation used a simplified Lily/Nim polyglot as an example, so I’ll refer you to [that post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101159/tips-for-creating-polyglots/113157#113157) if it’s not obvious how I abused this language feature.

### CoffeeScript

> `###;console.log 39`

One of Lily’s features is that `###` is used to attach a docstring to a function, so if you use this without following it with what Lily views as a function, then Lily will error out. And since `###` is CoffeeScript’s block comment, the `###` on the INTERCAL line had to change. So the final two `#` got cut from this line and moved to the line after Lily’s `#[` block comment so Lily would view it as a comment instead of a doc string.

### Julia

> `=#print(17)#`

By moving the two `##` for CoffeeScript, a hole was opened up on the INTERCAL line. The spacing on this line is delicate because Minimal-2D is looping between the beginning of this line and the line two below. So I had to fill the space. The first byte I filled with Julia’s initial block comment command (`#=`) by moving the `=` down to fill the space. This move also helped as a partial solve for Labrynth’s final answer, which I talk about later.

### BrainF***

> `+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-]`
>
> `>+.---.>`

The second space opened up by the CoffeeScript move still needed to be filled, and the `>` at the end of the line above was an easy move. This character set up the proper memory cell for BF so it just needed to go anywhere in the correct order of BF characters, and since there were no BF characters between the old and new location, no problem.

### Brain-Flack

> `({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})`

In the process of working a different solution, I had an epiphany about old this Brain-Flak code: `(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})`. I was using `\` to escape out `{`  for Japt, but I could put a `1` in each curly brace, to give Japt something to do like I did in the PicoLisp answer. But what would that give me? Trading a `\` for any other instruction was at best an even byte swap. But wait… Retina.

Retina had a string of `1`s in the same line that were somehow integral to its answer. So I tried moving the `1`s over to Brain-Flak’s code to handle Japt and it worked almost entirely.

Thutu, didn’t like having the last `\` removed from this snippet, so I left it. I had one fewer `1` in Retina’s code than I required to fill Japt’s braces anyways, so it all worked out rather swimmingly to golf down 5 bytes and produce this: `({({1})({1}[(1)])}{1}\{})`.

Later I found I had to swap around `1`s because The above tokenized `{1}` for Incident. So I swapped around the `1`s to make `({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})`.

### Modular SNUSP

> `<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.`

While I was looking at the big line, I decided to look at some other languages.  Modular SNUSP is encased in a pair of `[]`, to protect the code from SM/BF. But SM/BF were both already jumping this code because of the `[` on line 14. Cut.

### Thutu

> `|/=1/24=x`

I never bothered to learn how Thutu works, but I do know that it’s answer was somehow produced in part by `|=/=1/24=x=9`, so I experimentally, removed various characters and verified that the same results were produced, and found I could get there with less. Golfed!

### INTERCAL

> `[PLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVE]`

I swapped some Latin `FAC`s for English `DO`s because it was byte saving, and all the `D`s worked safely as Fusion starting points with INTERCAL’s new location.

### Hexagony

> `"(}23!@)"`

Here’s where things got messy. I got it in my head that Hexagony’s code module should really, really go inside C/++’s preprocessor directive on line 1. The benefit here is that Hexagony would be permanently be solved because its pointer always starts on line 1 heading to the right, which puts its output command prior to any hexagon wrapping non-sense. And with Cubix in the mix now, providing basically the same headache… Well let’s just do this with 1 language, yeah?

So `}23!@` appears in line 1 now,  and everything that follows is a consequence of that move. Note that the `}` is still needed to clear the top value of the stack due to the preceding `(` in the final solution.

### Pyth

> `#16`
>
> `;'[af2.q]`

The first problem was moving Pyth’s answer to somewhere else. I spent quite a while looking through Pyth’s documentation for a way to pop the string off the stack or something, before stumbling into the answer. For Pyth, a space preceding any command causes the command to be skipped. This actually works for a full string, like where our Hexagony capsule is residing, so the first x characters of the polyglot became `#16  "}23!@"`, with the 16 here now being Pyth’s answer.

### Underload

> `(22)S`

Underload needed the Hexagony capsule to exist within a pair of parenthesis, but if too much of the polyglot went into that first set of parentheses Underload would bomb out. Also, our last few solutions had an open ended `(` on line 1, which was preceded by a `\` for Retina to escape it out of consideration. (Retina didn’t like the imbalanced `()`.) But now, this solution didn’t work for Retina if there was already a pair of `()` in the line. The new solution opens and closes 2 sets of parenthesis on line 1 to get around these problems. Fortunately Underload didn’t complain before a new set of parenthesis could be opened on line 2.

Meanwhile, inserting more text in line 1 prior to the `v` causes line 2 to require a bunch of filler characters prior to its `>`, which is the Befunge code path. The largest piece of lose code that could fill the hole was Underloads answer statement `(22)S` which got moved earlier in line 2 along with some related Alphuck `P`s that needed to appear prior to `s`’s  for its jump. (More on Alphuck later.)

### Trigger

> `GkGGZ`
>
> `Z222999`

Trigger’s jump code got pushed out of line 2 by Underload’s shift, so it had to go somewhere and the earlier the better. The Japt string '[af2.q]’ in line 1 turned out to be a well-hidden location, so I plopped Trigger jump code there after Pyth quit, making '[af2.q] GkGGZ’.

You may notice that the letters in the jump code got changed again, this is partly because I wanted to leverage the space for a polyglot unique Incident jump token, and partly because of a problem caused by… wait never mind. I just uppercased the `G`s for no good reason. Ok, whatever.

### SMBF

> `<]+<[.>-]>[`

With characters spaces to fill prior to the `>` on line 2, I moved the `[` back in the line to help fill the hole. You might think as I did that it might be possible to golf off this character all together, as well as the `]` on line 1, but this causes Retina to get grumpy, as it did with Underload. And even if you think about throwing a `\` prior to `[` might fix Retina, you would be right, but it would cause 05AB1E to fail in a way that I presume cannot be fixed with a zero byte budget. So I didn’t bother.

### Turtlèd

> `#)"14"`

I managed a line 1 character order that didn’t necessitate the `# #` therein. So the turtle no longer pokes his head out of the shell before finding `“14”`.

### Labrynth

> `# >36!@`

The maze got kinda messed up by all the shifts for Hexagony. The biggest problem was that the old solution relied on the second character in the polyglot being a space (aka maze wall). Now the pointer turns right once it passes into the `1` on line 1, which was a problem because the `/` on line 2 set the top of the stack to 0, which caused the pointer to really want to go straight.

*Trial and error montage*

This got solved by putting a `>` in the path of the pointer after the `/`, which is an instruction to shift all of row 3 one cell to the right. This puts the pointer in column 3 as it continues its zero valued straight path to the `>` in `>36!@` which again shifts; this time row 4.  From this point, the pointer turns to head down line 4 which from that point forward is a 1 way trip to the end of the maze.

@SnoringFrog made a gif of Labrynth's code path to help someone with an answer, and I thought it was cool and helpful enough that it should be added here.

[image]

### Japt

> `` `|1|6$` ``

I golfed some other bytes off of line 1. It was all trial and error and I have no idea how Japt works for the most part. I guess I can say that in the `#` near the end of line 1 causes Japt to take the ascii value of the `)`. Most everything else is a mystery.

### Minimal-2D

> `#=<xR+++++[D>+++++++L`
>
> `#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x`
>
> `#D>xU/-<+++Lnd`
>
> `#R+.----\).>]|`

Part of the line 1 refactor was to place the D early enough in the line to minimize the amount of empty space thrown into line 8, where Minimal 2-D catches the code path From the `D` to `L`.  I ended up being able to place the `\D` just after the `v` in line 1, which ended up being the same column it started in, so I didn’t have to touch line 8.

### Befunge

> `7 7*,;68*,@`

The space between the `7`’s on line 2 is a spacing shift for Minimal-2D’s `D` on line 1 so that Fission doesn’t pass through a character. The 7 that Fission would otherwise pass through here doesn’t actually cause a problems, but the space is part of White space’s answer, so it needs to appear somewhere on the line, and this seemed like a better place than most.

### Befunge-98

> `>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@`

For some reason the Hexagony capsule gave a problem for Befung-98. I believe it was producing non-deterministic results for a while there. I don’t know what the issue was, because I went back and looked at an old solution for inspiration and saw that there was a @ before it quit in prior solutions, so I tried it and it worked.

### Reticular

> `;#:p'34'\`

Reticular, Haystack, and Reng, which all wrap around the polyglot when they hit the first `/` on line 1, had to be redone because we’re wrapping on a later column than in previous solutions. Now the code path goes through the `6` on the final line, which gets buried in a stack values for these languages, and continues to the `\` on the next to last line which catches the code path, and pushes these languages’ pointers to the left.

Reticular was the problem child of the bunch because it had a command in the Hexagony capsule, which it traversed prior to wrapping, that caused the old solution to break on Reng’s code. I solved this by throwing Reticular’s code first in the order.

### Reng

> `~nJ`

The `;`, which terminated Reticular, gave Reng some problems because it views the command as a reflector. So Reng gets a `#` jump command to skip past the `;`. But Reticular threw an error on the `#`, so I tossed in a preceding `:` to indicate that the following `#` was to be pushed onto the stack as a string.

### Haystack

> `|o51`

Haystack’s old solution was too long, unless I was going to wrap up to another line, but I no longer needed to use the old solution because I was terminating Reticular earlier, so I reverted to the old solution of outputting a string rather than ascii values, which was shorter, allowing the 3 languages to exactly fit in one line.

### Minkolang

> `$$$`
>
> `#<.>"3"O.`

The change to remove the space before the first number in line 1 caused Minkolang to fall through time a in column 4. The upshot of this was I could golf out a bunch of the junk that had to be thrown into Minkolang’s code line because it previously couldn’t start with a `#`. The `.` in the final solution is both needed as a placeholder, and to detokenize `.>`.

### Incident

> `kGkG0l0v0@O6O4/1k1k0l(0i0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100^_`
>
> `^_^_`

I think @SnoringFrog, during his week of all-nighters and fantastic code golfing, changed the incident token `0e` to `0ee`, presumably to make Cubix work. I found I could once again set this token back to `0e` to save a few bytes.

I also went through the polyglot and re-tokenized any Incident tokens that were littered about. I ended up putting just a few back. One I mentioned is the `.` in `<.>`. Another is the `!` in `[!PPP` on line 2. The `nd` in `+Lnd` is a detokenizing string as well that I couldn’t otherwise fit into a place holding gap.

### PicoLisp

> `}#(prin 45)(bye)`

The location of PicoLisp’s instructions became kind of a problem because Prelude’s parenthesis budget got shifted by Underload’s change. So I just moved PicoLisp’s answer. Putting all these parenthesis so close to column 1 was just asking for trouble anyway.  Code is now in the Python line, which is safer.

### Alphuck

> `ssseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp`

This is my first time working with Alphuck and it is surprising how much it doesn’t feel like BrainF***.  Just the fact that all the characters show up all the time makes the language much harder to work with. And it’s much more difficult to read. Anyways, the PicoLisp move changed the `[]` balance (speaking in BF terms) so I had to add back some `s`’ in the evil line and the last line.

### Prelude

> `46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)`

Prelude had all kinds of rearrangements due to the Underload move. But these we’re mostly just the spacing shifts we’ve all become accustomed to. The one large change was to move the `)` now seen in `#R+.----\).>]|` from the end of the line above. To leave it in its old home required too many spaces. Experimentation showed there was a happy home a few columns left of its original spot and the the characters to the left were all rigidly incorporated into the Minimal-2D solution. So the next best move was to go down a line where Minimal-2D was more flexible and Underload was still happy.

### Retina

> `({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})`
>
> `|1|6`

Retina had a small problem with the Prelude move discussed above however. The line change put the hanging `)` on a cares-about-symbol-balance line, so preceding `\` was thrown in to placate Retina. We were still byte saving from the number of spaces Prelude needed on the line above, so we were good with this result.

### Cubix

> `@O6O4/`

While I loved the elegance of the Cubix Placement in the last answer it was fragile, and yeah I broke it with all this stuff I did. So I stepped through the Cubix interpreter to find a good place to catch the code path and ended up hooking it in the Incident/While line, which is a pretty good place to catch it because the Cubix module could mostly slide freely throughout the line. The only catch was that you had to be very careful not to place Cubix inside an incident token. All the incident tokens in this space start with either a `1` or a `0` and are followed by a letter, other than `x`. `x` in this space appears to be a de-tokenizer. Fortunately Cubix slipped in between tokens without a spacer.

### Whitespace

> 

Or

> `␉␉␉␉`

There were a few hidden tabs left over from earlier Whitespace solutions that were still needed as whitespace for whatever other languages were in the region. So I swapped these out for plain old spaces, just for the convenience of reading.

And that was the last of my code changes. Here are the few languages I didn’t touch.

### evil

> `meePaeueewuuw`

### Cardinal

> `x%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x`

### C

> `#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"`
>
> `#include<stdio.h>`
>
> `main(   )/*/`
>
> `` #()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*' `` ``

### C++

> `#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"`
>
> `#include<stdio.h>`
>
> `main(   )/*/`
>
> `` #()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*' `` ``

### Rail

> `$'main'//`
>
> `#-3o4o#`

### Python 2

> `print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))`

### Python 3

> `print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))`

### Ruby

> `print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))`

### Perl

> `print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))`
>
> `__DATA__=1#//`

### Perl 6

> `#>27.say#`

### 05AB1E

> `"26`

### Pip

> `''25`

### Whirl

> `0l0v0@O6O4/1k1k0l(0i0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100`

### Fission

> `#.\."12"__*`

### V

> `dggi2`

Or

> `␛ dggi2␛`

### ><>

> `;n4`

### Nim

> `]#echo 21#`

### Going Forward

While trying to prove to my insistent brain that Octave was an impossible addition, I instead proved that actually will fit in here. It requires a bit of comfort with tricking Japt around curly braces and a rather interesting 3 language solve, but it is possible.

The polyglot currently executes in Objective-C (clang) to produce 38 (the C answer). I’ve looked for a language native method for differentiating from C, but haven’t had any luck. Clang has pre-defined macros like **TIME** that are not used in the C/C++ compiler we’re so far using. But I’d prefer to find a language native method of differentiating Objective-C is possible. Any ideas?

And along those lines, I think we’re at a point where we’re soliciting ideas from the community. I know my idea bank is running low, so if you have any suggestions, please leave a comment.

Also, a special shout out to @WheatWizard for suggesting [Glypho](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho) as a possible addition as well. I haven’t looked too deeply at it yet, but I am intrigued.

Comment: Oh wow, I just realised how the Thutu works now. It's inputting EOF from stdin, and then misinterpreting that EOF as a command, which just happens to be the command to exit the program. (Meanwhile, the INTERCAL appears to be crashing with an error after printing output; there's likely a missing GIVE UP statement. That probably needs to be fixed.)

Comment: Oh, and on the subject of Objective-C, I believe it's a strict superset of C (i.e. all C programs will run unchanged in Objective-C). Thus, adding it into the polyglot is going to have to rely on implementation-specific details somehow (such as evaluation order, which isn't specified in many cases in C); it's maybe not impossible, but it's going to be harder than normal. Perhaps we should create a chatroom for discussing polyglot ideas? Doing it in comments is awkward.

Comment: @ais523 Interesting that INTERCAL gave an exit code of zero in the test driver. Do we have a compiler discrepancy with Tio? I think a polyglot chat room is an excellent idea.

Comment: It's a syntax error, which has error code ICL000I. C-INTERCAL returns the error number as the exit code; it's just that 0 for a syntax error is indistinguishable from 0 for success. As for the chat room, let's discuss things [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development).

Answer (score 13):

## 99. [*99*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47588/write-an-interpreter-for-99), 2943 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8ââââ(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>â
# 36!@â`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?24O6O@?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))â\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss 9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppppðð¨ðð¨ð¬95ð¬ð¥â¡
ðð¢ðððððððð

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#defineâ x(d)â#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27""e ' Zing  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts(  "92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0â
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8âdggi2âM`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003033 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3032 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zVtbc9tIdn42Kv9gX1ogxwBIAiAoUeJd0tjyxrPjlWLZ45RJ2oZAkIQFAhwAFCnLdOUpVbk8JKk8pJJKNklVqvYh/yKv@RX7C/YfTL7TDV4kUZInl6pAJtBAnz59bn36nO72mR0Pf/opQxc7Cf3LgR8mLHHjhPUi78KNDPbtJTuwvbhc2pYkDhWFvYnjBQOWDF3mBeNJwvqe78aSYyesxcYpFoMKLMMi1@4JMKkfRoyasNG5zzzmjMfszLeHhsN8D7DPihXmjsKPHlrF4YggEzcaRy7uMQtct8fiset4fc/hPTJ3lrhB7IVBbDDPOWdTz/dZz/XRYEWGUwAyNonXPolODakXSgyXM75B9PIt6wImcBeMu2M74oyHbMylsOB/GtnjMYiUMuwUhCfeyI2Zlygxc@3YI2miSewGPS6z8VLOIbODdS7ZhWczG/ROIo47dqME7BkcLxu6kQuUNnU@iOwRU6eRl0AEJNJDduLaEXsVua6GXqAKN3bsMei41iU6C6mHhBgxuMoaDeXo@JkC1YkWhj1OpEy0/eqPvpNsZjRZ9n0dv6Ys16WjXz9lV9kOlUEFkEG940i1Ndb8wmKz03Hxm1ln5iCaS8AqQSo@M8NxYtr6GATqCQg0bSpSSb8oGWN/rWPWuKGLNYMSUD1ogz0P2A8FzpkziSIXdKyEap@DaT8MBpAnmI0mAckjYLtFqMAJg15cYO4FpBYGQkfhlEv41dCD0mJSiX0GAdkOyV4MBi5QDAfYXirRRb9x6E84HFrGCRkgpIKmhPF5n/3A@rbnUxPUEypBdeTGEz@hNpOgR5ofeYHbM9iCDCfsEdAovEB3NpDyDxg/o7VRx4kCMBQRclap6nd/9Q@9wQB4Dh0njHqpuf7AeqEzGYFgmxNrwxTJYMPA9jlZgCtQ76I5Oriwfa9nJ9R9cJl2wYngvU7Did9jITqMph6G1tC@wHDs910ncYWRh5MENBbYyD4XvsITlgvGR/YZFMs74H1ztnV28ARaclxhMvpokvQrTB8fMSU236n7NXV/q@OCNs3QclnTHNRhb0aOf8Kbcp/h/HC40idZzysvpHHkj4cTeA3UBPEY/iQiYTo22InJrSTwfwV2xgXNfRFMnQ/SqatELjvDyF4wxm1E2AC112nkphhWOl3AXTcxt7dmYbBOGFkS33ITfjhFx5w2cqKw6YA6twc2ukpShg4FQ6JH/uU6a@cBLJ2wnbmsop950A7ZAZxNqow1HgG@XRIwwCa0tzYoRvYlsDjCSa80ybw@lDyC3UaXzHFpMGBUuMLTUScTbhixBzsK@6yol8rlB5SfROah/hbe45N5r46J@RtqPmR9d8p8OxhM7AEMOQzQxHYcd5ykIwicxAnGyE1HyD/qqVc34qGUPbjZN/duqb9f64O8j9Be6qNtMnsIagRR6z5GObOjAR@JrOdFGC/@5c3eAXBxo3P5A4FcI@CDfAcJi6kJRubOXGeSYLjBkKdDzxnCdom6QAxY4R1vdo9P673D5ej9ZddEjNV6XJIMc/mJyLgThU4avY0HXp9Qta594Mpf/3A/ZjsebUAcLkmEh1r7api2AdtLhYb5/JRiCbi/xeTNR9YywFjKEwL@jiamyP1xAoXBnr1BQCB2sJz41zyjFwcKpgov9iB1msLJ1l89P6b54I0rohjIXcxl6848REyD5ukUTRULJUiuMwyZHjAlpUGV@Yz6EWSZceTwgr4WRsiaATmpJC9etUD0UcRoNydU1roNx7tUCqwty90C5jA/hgkFE9/HyyTgQ0x1tSvYmuPGsYEBA9kaFI@AOjnvavPrgMkwCqfMnWt1ZVN3P1MhTyZn3uz/oUYcokvcwdWaGvinr9HDLcCFImQ5Fd0tCC67J@GI/Dx7wzkmer@NMDf0MR9I48tkCE@nO0y2m@HYBUnXPIkCOhGkq1qdh3SKYnwMvUC9Ura2tpSa0lIKKO2j1KDSPpXyKO3zks5LBGdQibco8BLVtnkL@tZV5u0F5pnWJdXOKG795I1Vu12rbXcLdttKnyV6aphMMHcAWqcH8Chas0lFTZNbUzBqnPUlwf4rKOd7hHzse49m4j4CxFXqIC0760iyEMb2dV8qr2pKIlq9MEcQnzG@3BxFyOuoeAMEcOch2eiq9L5oWOVrKJD33G7Z9@Ihv10DvUXW7RreOh6d9fltA0AtDQMQU1CWRHLhrowikTCE5U852CgMQkEK5OUFtvmSPwzMHpvoue6krxFz5mLMD1zzzAuo/ACYXq1wyP7ZmXcXKORCpC@eG8CiydkmsSE8G96ax9k1wSeTKPHdXvr8zz/pQQG31TO0L2ME9OfLwnvIjVSl9@/UVtqUXvhts2Y/Tnykew/gcGwK4m1/WdiMq8ZeujB/aDbgWR4o9cEbRThwdbftG0PDn/TcxXMzUi7D6@GAaB14I645PCm24Z7njuY3ghnRnpKeyA/tnikSUc9dqVII3Z3ZgzC4NNdmNSM6@woaF/EGW2WeyXCSTMSdks2HlOaN6XffYEwhi2X7zHLNMLbPvDskSETs3mW0YiyQm9b7vn0uiu@puJlVwUzkDZDZLp53gSHaQ0A@th3XnPLHnf4jmMRjrkxeugdf5Iv7XSBe4GBmDVaFuwDBps9vP8fkuCE4GAdEKi326Gsi8m4I1bfPLmkqG/58@6EOB/k80@E7mk4@X9xmerjKxVbLSuPx3e0dJ21frW5uLVagOAInRNrsPjQfYVLxRravl3prxTv962LqX5U2uR/7wkZQ4NsxDCRJxexeQC38dp/R0jzhTHw7WpXuMdkVOYuU@66sbdVm7Dmh76WWuXjZ0EFAYd7NkGiFhtYV@W3VlN5Sl/kUUQ9NvF/u9Zuhk1CydIfpfIVHEnkKZYJrtmCEd4nLCaf0u3PADsMLV9w3T0GfNlL1FR5H97kxINa@3bznPGShtA7Eb5s94flGqhLH3/i9xl6EYYRENWYlo3ivejaacez5YcxO@f0@WSBFj2Nx32zA62Lz7EB3hmJYLcubm20kis9o7JDf71Cu7Q9Cf7cyMG3c7rSASdQnx54@v9apLZ2SZT3olJbhSxhY6fNOb36Ofw8ZBy2AwH17FMcsi5sN5U4Plkb8dzOIMJ8WvDYz96xYWVpWFLv3mlSNHUbOcGpf3gv10Mxxl5gXM0eNFut5IPw/62bn/m56X@elbqHdux/tNfWe@y7cNL/fUiorFa2f2cIqFr/eZ/X9iTtxN/qQ47OPLgznq4Pie4kqpmzU2Kdz/16cX0U2zeL0dq/PsX0P4/zBGKbGThBEn4QPJACDYDK@psv17GESvHxgTDwJw97Pt9Sl16k8HArV2KmbPEDF0ShEchqOEBIEX6HZNFTn24rifk2z/MsK80fvCeKJ6F68y4UeBKMILqAs7zzWEb1slGvqSEr3k7pMVapV5FSBm1zS/TZCvtbxkm9oLVeY40K6E4dvXpTuu8TLzc3M88CJXL7evFhBYxlaBZ@MELYlYWQwDqeqdj6vaZJoRGHAIADYAopvL9EKv9i5ihnisYTDen3WbrPs1axWrFlz1mRyTWbdrsDK15qPZmO@L/RSNG1n7W4zq@i6klU6QY0VFQ7q@vDKG0Hta3B9jz8EnSvWWWCP@KYClRec1sXOBYIl2q4a2kEPierrwOOLg04YifV3scnzilYB/uO3vXQXb@CCyZEXYwgOAtp5DkfuMJzui37T3g/HY5t2AQkHciNfLB/qTw5ZPPUSZyg27xDLvX72qpLuvKT74Xg5IbWvUSGUiqo@aLAToTRBTS90hf2kHS9bLZhCgDwZBWzq9ZJhbCDyCRyX7@wsdhtASURgQRKFZH8F9pz1XErU@Ornxwl064fhOV90JUr@47divwmVHpkQlRfd8w3QtR4ZHJbFN3kcJ5yA6gWST24UpiAqCRlh/oSGDazfFd815gxtvhEGS9QX20DUjdgKenJ4yvQjptAGPu0K1b2@mj18@csf2sVu8wsbme5//olJC9FcbvI3@p4VywW2AKnPya7Wq4uoXtUqTM7O5JQt2irmO6NLoxKjialU5upabOuM@C4ztzt3yrd1@N5dQFkMbd8GMcYHXjWOWgyaZlad@N7IS5h@mrAynXKAu7NREvvSjM4N0BYFNcnO2Gc2JFvRHWaVi3gTAvFpV2zU/Haxhra9vtZpPnXPJnxd4KJklLabnJ3s@2ajxUuR2wtp37T9rjPtmvFCKp3O7JtiaQaxhRHAH5s0co5@/fQqa7SKnz/HCIRkea7U@Vo0De/s1cnzk6PTV4evXp9CjHPBZeZZGI3slYsgIxj7iFCHoc83oiGPyHPjh93GI@43pEcpoKqyrM0aiAsYPNSjpWNJxSrrclYURR33JMu6G5Wp@@h7LHV17IRrO1WsEq@7ucLCAEh4GJMT@NUF8TCcqw3uirMjsyYY0sEQB18SvHzbxNj1Wg4vBL5P7xB6ysY6FGd1BbUZiHgVwCndAkYQuZGJ@f8S5WPMIw9TTlAPUQ5g6aHe1zp@dvj8@9cvj273vdZtCnMLZGkha2d/jmbILOAH@9zCaX95YTdhej5g4Rjg94di08r2V64tXu4/kSX1yTH7GNs0KPjqXEyDm5EfMdihH8OR9nrwDGeXCTkWeFSx5bTcd5IzEICxnOcKTJYINm7e3ieG45giBnM@iMZZDscxx5uOWnRc83d/9Q/ieEUnQfnP0nIf5b8U5XcmCej2frygcSkaEssPz09YjNlKMD6yZ2s80YRBE5IXIH73RpDgBRcIgQtiV/yu8KjtHyBPKAHCJM9Hzo7350ZddZgk45pp0vyORLpv8AV7dwY9wFcaSD3NHyd02gX@2dwt7@5YJojULxYI@SbqgBaRBUJNq8GEpAtv3Pxw5rBGo8HkGHGf29ytC0GaWfvdtvxhSWgWsJIIBdoMbdBk1QJ1rbSZmrXzlkZNaRQqlsK6dczyQi@YKFReAIhGn4NUHjJmojAVFe3HurOEO9XLRYiD@CII2YjkxM88LRDpQCRwa7J0y3ZXi8W0SbZmzca6GuQ3BHZKYDV5k@kwWMg/b7CcAOU/F@V2p6h/6W46r7O0ncPbx3LUm4dqiBd2cBqEtHnwDLQytWSWtk1rV1sbJ3KKCtTSqPgMlBgHGFeO630Mx/Hhk6Pn3x2fnN46VsIhlZtgClNajXxHNwrt7rKg3LD5hUi/fWaevvj22UKQ61SlVTep2oT8JmF3dPZGLMvf7opX3OrIKn4tYr6HrD/jaeoGRpa15hrgE7GGeKtXVbuat7uNVifI3Or@86YzXxkjR8e8UOrE/MSXwjY4mOeLzYZX4TnM457DLHpCEN6n9WMti60KOjNSapk998KkQw6SsdrEkLNq4xq1mjh4I2Sw6B5@Iv2StWT0u@rLkW4tCK8TIjLkcEnJtZZLYRPPxyKz4@fW7ABBfeQ5AjrmzlXkf/yQFTKA58kqaUAiQssgPDe65HkAhvlygbXn8bV3O7pMOVjWnLojT3@1oIcG/eokAZxQGCVIP@Kh753V7WZ7xpb77PcdMjDise8lKu3uzwzKr8CNqhEDVsN36XBAo9pNTyKwxYGBPD9zcDKBvE7CMVvltE/dRekl0hr2dALksACXfTcZAa7PHy9d8vAu@3WoozHkqCyIaKMXNeXBGPXK6N0YurOeN8AsoWoFOJRvLGt1WsHW8shFFfhQIapf0srxumB@1gmLNYnZbdvwgp47U5WpotW6JB18V6ZvLhRNvmUD/JhHeuajd/O8x2Ls20k6CJdnJW6O72p1Oa6vD5tq1RjGEh2BQGSOHk@T6HsUMf@p/ZE9ZuokoGAlZgbjr2pHDQpxEmlMb9FcNGUBy@d5TI8HrzAYb9nnJc@nQ4YqHS1VzSb0TF/joEePT96YtS3D6KLMO9FYltLxJwgVKJHVJASAaFLjaDF54q9GFE2RvRBF4pnl3UqUS0eA2ljNB/JgyAcgZMG5Zq3HbOUIViNQSLVaraXauO7dqgxmcXseMUyg3eC1FtEi5JtudUNqdASaDjchS/PgUA5@5QYBxqsKmxlhdDJ7AiOLtMLiPH5heWpyjcA/THfOb07RR8qVHyIQyZp1ng/W55iNP3RYJ@n0OwFNyfVL8xemYdav1KzfvDQRRWktNTtsWvntXD6fDXJqNqA44vFjSiPnWYQp7w3ZkGcA0rO@VocxI6xpZoN61m6o2V6zlOMt8JrPa1do8CU2jausPTezjxEVFPAlEkNTzcYajYWiYVhz0EfDI2sWYDBXqszkGR0@pe6zXj5PNBjZ90TAF7NzmudzROfU5IlrPY1OzcFo4UOu6eSnnzLWLhKl/d1tNdwvbW/lMixzIJu5ztO3b59c1JW23S8ZP3ZPzk9O/ljrqErmybFs7ch1ljOljJkrft4zzQ8fPiBuY@2W0TK6WltXum21tbeXqxd2K7nCQcFSCvUM862iZWlqqaSddnaCuud547jXwy8c0uk0RC41Us0jXKp1oijlbeX0HZ2q2t/CH/@Ha/lK9y3@Jf3MQW5fWxpTf5xJmdYj2NL27tbBI5Dq5vlVqx0wKfNFylxKmQ@ND1IG4Wmm1erO5/lGu9EwWq1ZS@@22lLmSsrM5lKmJJNoclKmOWu85CjaT1sCV/5HiPl7PBt6tz0@@f7o8PSoUGromdKzwyeF0unrbzMW3sqrV6rcpteXR4dPj1@/KpREq18@/@Ho9Qm@x93WwUHe0HX9wGh1QcXsm3wr30yShL19n8PYeNqavTb1Bjr9Xsq85JB6B2R0NMB/ljLtTFvdL@0c7x4f7JeKfvGiaJ1b5y/C4@U/9uL4GBXerPgxjIrD4tDqWZY1K7qvi5fFy1lxFB5bPRRd/BVHKHrF/qw4KAbFwLLWEd3zb3QcvjgOgSpEs2RWTAhrsY/n4Pj4BZD10fFH/HnFIhE4K17gX9G3@PXuPZLaYqcjtWGm3fLuuLT7Y5s7/XK123ZnXtKVWUHptKvVqtKtZ8y40zGFrcslGCpBzOfv3z89fHX4/r1J6euskc0f5PUDXM1WvpE@9jO9FonQaGx1JEWdvnnzhn5vphdTUeKFN1P2Jr3wZsp7FTkMD1LQN6vnmymuizuQXC@wa5eqtsvdq7mmaY86Sl0RnKiqi0BGla3OrNRnJZnHB1U4CGub5qDdstZq7ZbxvlvRdLVItTvaO6vRSKtKWhjJykwOI4VdzcWfejVvqPzS6E/T6GN6b2kqqrUy3mZX6qyhNlT6hk/U6mreoiKHu0KprWpdbT4X33BXtYbA2dLAIGVg/0f/wpjFY6Zk5hmaFAK2U9aQ37nazq5ayVfTv@YWmFHlbWUbPMqKrbTbB7nt3N5Oe7@b6@bURs7IdVrd2fqlKRkGk1tYTdPKkPSkjFF/KVslWSErqtOqZui7ho98a7taV9ScuFhueVWsaj6XP2jnqlXRWy73eUtDcyCXcWVgaUxljVZjqf6VJWgt/K5YKmCU51ewCFGHaUVNlys7nVmxyOHrZ83sVcae1zl6NpcX0KlhcfSqUufr2PKVnLWjttWV53L26mxOc2/O0visWd6p13M7orxXqcPZW7m0poiatIgKN7YdPsLg38mSFIhYA1PNM3fgBVJmfM208@Vy2SzhPvtm96g0k@q03isWl2VdFpbOKlWOMBPHrCohvDuDoqdsr4jw3fftiIX9/pb4jjgVCb6LUMH1fVopoTAO0YzfmyJ12JIy8AgIYlCNa3RiuxPXnU4mU3d5PfHimv3xI7IQfv3@N3/3p/j9Fr@/Ec@/@fdqme6//81f/9vv/ulfJDz/4ve/@dt//f1v/vLv8fvH9Pf3N3@SRKxtsfLeomBJL2gVomqJPRmPPqMUuVXpD8HfaOIMaU/MS2heRbRblAySRqlUrZQr1e1SpVCpVnbK1m65XLBKBWuvslctFjClVqzdSrlqFSo71e2dnZ1qgVmlcnVPyrhBz@ubJiYrS5YZLyCpotONDToHGhrDFia/nttHTPmIzdSe9ijTW3xgkwqTtyudIvI4HvaqTGNX5HZVFiP7AelqsTCBtynvTyry7p5cy@Ep78vbKHJtz1RWVGCYstKRZa1d7e7Le2W5hhldVx5b@0zeqyIe3tuTtbrsDsqyvMtKe7LsInx9S9pkcn0OqhfiWPLD4KINg@Gn6xLVj5uCIlWuqoyrvNqRxYAQ1qWoirJXUhRNqQPJlrxuk1qd2AN3KXMIaeFe65GbTKJArerwIEyvavW5IOMP1uiIzhFy2xGFvbwb5Ly7VZk@A6ShVgl9q3yWqxUsvXAgCfPetaTMXOrR6a2dKqtX6xRbwOU2WlJWIVKUbSmjb4c7YSabzSIiedWSt@Vjo2GmYUbL5DFGh8IOmvCNRdTSYqYUubSr0KP/jyjmjUqZeBmwOJP/b14GemgCp1QnfyVnUg95STNfRxDU@JLhR3vYydVypTr9vw61FyRdu3bKz7W2u0z78mvPv6ps6y0e/SMFnDPIdj4@rb7be1d59@L18evjZwe1Sq0CJ5aJP2th2foSfFfP1MbK9o6yjeimmRHMWXtaplXaM2L7MtNN9z7VnT2N4Y27qJKV6dM8vJyGb0/Ta6UN79OLEQ/vQEjlF73BwCv94sWHz1nTVBTGrOzuF70h/jVwe3IsVKzKu2VZoz3j@N37d@8zcERMLpVhdnkTYbNp/nEJw7pa3a3sZqSfTPO@1RvULvOfvovUYDLalAAdRt4Lm5LDYJkEofBi8smNlqOe0bCnvH7Yuv6Nu4Jrn/h/hsU3ieji44MKdjRwCnwNn@XoGHO7C5ew2P9RqZa2ILTljoUYQ6xYFztLhMKrL4vohYYtUtGi@Ej5juo1rTrzGoQMT6RJaQ90LVrkm1SktRFOhdfV6tL6VgynpIXWa7Sstc/nBfhckCX4cUY9wbaoW76CvBFtWTtq2lq7AdAudinn7hSVlM2vYQO5srrEUGA/m40b7ZERagueOAmryvT7ShVzKZcURnWJ2M6N69KvVEe7oky1/mX0@LHzbtwedevaqJnQM58fwfGdq54AySXNUVO36mMQW0/a@bzXbY60X6ljTvyoWQQw@ibMsXa11HTQTNUVa4VP7UD/EnQLz9pB3uoWJoXc2@angt0sFmb4QWwFv/AjhLcQpZo0P@WDut3Aj5Lma5KA48/b9es7ZGhyrvrNT2272yxqdR8N8/lnYAZ0xm0/n@9q6NxH5e2Gdf/xYzvvt2Z1X9c1gnq3vf@snaDQzTfpvabajdn@p/YE7Wsqnk1042sgHu2u6wD4QF8dMhbqW5EuaJwReTOQN2o2c2/3c29zza2tT@2ZPuoWhPhrxZXiifgZEb9uI2ru7bphcZHwmFCVv/Fq3xi5mMkFWB@EXBivtRQU5t6iZrwaDfP/Ag)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c)

### Explanation

*99* is a language that only cares about `9`s newlines and spaces. Each line falls into one of 4 forms (excluding nop lines) depending on whether there is a space before the first 9 or not and whether there are multiple space seperated groups of 9s or not.

Lines that have only one variable (group of 9s) and have no spaces before that variable are print statements. Lines that have only one varable but preceded by at least one space prompt for input. Lines that have multiple variables but no space before the first variable are assignment via alternating sum. Lines that have multiple variables and spaces before the first variable are conditional jumps.

The code this answer is based off is this:

```
9999 9 9          // assign 0 (9-9) to 9999
9 999 99 9999 9   // assign 881 (999-99+0-9) to 9
9                 // print 99 because 881/9 = 99 and 9 is a variable with an odd number of 9s
```

The code in the answer also includes a lot of conditional jumps that don't activate. These mostly came from adding extra 9s to prevent input statements from being in the code.

A code formatter for *99* has been added to the test driver if you want to see the full program.

The 3 main lines of the program are located:

- near the Evil

  ```
  #9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
  ```
- inside the Fortran/C89

  ```
  p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts(  "92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
  ```
- on the 5th last line

  ```
  #}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
  ```

#### Pip

Pip was the only language that gave me any real trouble and even that was fairly minor. I had to get a 9 into the last line to avoid the creation of an input statement for *99*. This was achieved by replacing the 5 that we were using as a dummy argument to the `#` operator with the 9

Comment: Heh. Good language choice.

Comment: @MDXF I have been waiting out since the late 80s or so to add it.

Answer (score 12):

## 12. [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission) (110 bytes)

Just adding yet another 2d lang... Streak of 3 2d-langs in a row, let's keep it moving folks!

```
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L;n4
#v0#_q@
#>3N.
#|\w*
#8  ^1b0<
#|
#M`
print(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5)
#jd5ki2
```

This prints **1** in Python **3**, **2** in Vim, **3** in Minkolang, **4** in <><, **5** in Python **2**, **6** in SMBF, **7** in Japt, **8** in Retina, **9** in Perl, **10** in Befunge, **11** in Befunge-98, and **12** in Fission.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY2WopG6oqG6j7WeSZcymUGyvGFDlzKdsZ@elzKNTHlWlzKFgoKcYZJBjZAPpeybwJXQVFmXomGX35eqkJiXoqCZX6RgqG@EYhpCGSaanIpZ0mnmGZnGv3/DwA)

#### Explanation

The only important piece of code is the first line

```
                These are the important bits
                    >------<
#v;2^0;7||"<+0+0+0+<*!2'!1'L;n4
                           ^
                   we start here by creating an atom moving Left
           (I could not use R for Right since that means Replace in Vim)

                       1'          sets the atom's mass to the ASCII value of '1'
                      !            outputs the atom's mass (as a character) 
                    2'             sets the atom's mass to the ASCII value of '2'
                   !               outputs it
                  *                program terminates
```

---

## Next...

If Fission is causing trouble, remember, you can move the Fission code anywhere you want, since the start of the program is only identified by the commands that create atoms, and the program ends whenever the atoms are destroyed.

You can also change the atom's start direction to suit your needs, `R` for Right (but Vim will interpret that as `Replace`), `U` for Up, `D` for Down (or Deletes entire line in Vim, can be useful).

Comment: This answer doesn't work with the Befunge93 answer, it only produces a 0 not 10.

Comment: @Tealpelican Works for me. Did you remember the ESC character between `j` and `d` on the last line? See the TIO link.

Comment: @Tealpelican https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69cZm0UZ2BtXlOjZKNtAIY2WopG6oqG6j7WeSZcymUGyvGFDlzKdsZ@elzKNTHlWlzKFgoKcYZJBjZAPpeybwJXQVFmXomGX35eqkJiXoqCZX6RgqG@EYhpCGSaanIpZ0mnmGZnGv3/DwA

Comment: Yeah my bad, for some reason chrome was removing it for me.

Answer (score 12):

## 34. [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail), 549 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::Q):  ␉␉␉␉ :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|>␉^*ttt*~++~~~%
#= >␉1#v#v0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111x0ex0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#[␉
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13 ))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{}) '#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"␉;
""""#//
=begin␉//
$'main'//
#-3o4o␉
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#]#echo 21 #//=#print( 17)
#   +/Jn~
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  #>say 27#$nd^_^_.Q222999/+23!@"26
```

As usual, `␉` is a literal tab, `␛` is a literal ESC character.

### Rundown

This program prints **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#jVjbetpIEr62XiE3FaEJkkEnfEhsDLGTOPMlO5NJYk/2wti4kRpoW@rW6GDg8@Hb273b@32BfY@93afYF8lWtwCDjTPLQWpa1VXVdeq/@F6RL/gsoskgEjnkNMshTNkVTR14M4F9wrKtxoaZpCwm6QRIkQ9FatVh/@2Q8IBqmlqeirAIGB9APqTAeFLk0GcRzbSA5NCGZMrekQOoQEpJWJJpfZGCXALxZQTTVwUyEcvJnKZJSvGaAac0hCyhAeuzQDEHOs4pz5jgmRYKTS4Mkgei5r8MijR8ri5NSKrUFZAo3Wdaj1KSJChPq8AR6pCzmGbA8moGlGRMGgeXZJSHaqfJ3GwCCF9UGK4YAYL7KFLFO6Npjpo6ii8MaUqRJZHCBymJwRylLMfdSEMcwGdKUjhOKbVQChqQZgFJUI8lkShMSAm53IijDL23Vz387X0VDV6ucEiSa5V04/jLR42A0wKj28RvS9eb2uGnd3BtdOQYtUBm6JQkNYkFrTvI3E6H4nfs99xBeqshVw2tEoErktxFziTNUb37kX3VcJJoQSzsPfDEQhCUVCH6Aj5w@FZX@wqKNKWoxb1JySVuORJ8gNbEraYFl9bgsO2hAwLBw6wO9AptJnjpITFS9j0eMnRZJh1CemgeEkjLl5GtzImxjUE0tedMbiaiQtHhyixnUSQNjEslxw99@AZ9wiK5BJ9LVqXWKc2KKJdrCh5Kv8eM09CBmRqBCCVRLK5QHEGmagJjPl7IFKUUEqMbhNqqfPTff/wzHAyQz0EQiDScBus3CEVQxKgwUcoSDEQZroKTSKmFdHUpvVyOAq5IxEKSS/F8MhWhlFBSR6KIQhAoMB2xjMKQXGFe9fs0yGkZ4qLIUcc6xOSyzG9Wxi1uPCY9dKwSoGTjtlWQ2HGR91@BnRxCNXPPzNe75uvnHYr6WI61brjuoIkR5qyrKfxV/VGwfDu496EmQ@YA@nQEEeGDggxwW4LjAhIENMmn9kS7ZDla7GFSqEl7muFONtSM/YeSVaRPc39BhozFMvum@UqkEQIRx@gAO0KfA0kHyi8QshStF00eSkeCqwfC9XNJsqTAuf6ECrMyhVFNxzQocjQ@rcNoyIIhjJR2vHRfmSsPxePUonQMQLs/Fy2V8dsvGprjzqekGk@ysKWjH/PBGiBZtZcmVEwsTqgNqkJ8JOs5Ru6s6srMuC/y882jNT7KmpLSPwq0LiYoG3BJQvi8Yi8ENct4FbOcZQxNJGsvwyfHH36TqfxXWp4kaKSyDC3mocBzBZdPa6t8MLOYRoOhAJtDdaqDqatSeIFquVkaqIG9UP91y0FzmdJs6tGM0UV5JD6shdB@TKdEVutwouundSw/UYb@5kUU4Y@Cq4QwqXWNgRHQLHMwujFXHXmQoHZ6jVq3y4T5MBUjoLdWs7pKnHLIMe75Fyy58AvDain6WKDvz2B1Vo/lEdXR9GSCQIBvLEevfv@kUZ4V39yYYCYmk9UZrS@yUgt@ZfxSSM@78WzU9Rx/a4kFYoXHK/ssG6rLEukjtR4/UauzuNdXlxUEXIbWA3upB7HgohSOFmKcuF/VzcEMXaXBciIsiX9D0VUDau9suD3G3R7tP0X5/s2bD4qm3@uxp4jQDBIYze4ryNKit8pKPZINHxVKWLLzcZHmkR26ubzT//wtRHs/9saQTDI8Py/ngy6nI@kZu/@kc6ZL5Q91We3IiyJCbPUnPAIiz0wSzQeree3CV4rRjmcaV5AKNY0iTEc0GRaMx@GMmRAVIZ3dVzNVNlyut8BZLM@LROLWJ1Y8OCBKgRJWpJEgoVsCPUbvvVfamY7JQPCJu1B8nLT3f6g1q@Fwj@zyYZEX5VXCuT/zE0vk90fpNqX0tg7e@IfT2xP0qMT2U3FapkiKlcR@H5FLtyeH3T4OV2@13EzKBogdZ/enyGimiozdE@LSLvF65uKxiogmIQFVqXb/c2UM/YpHc4SQ/ejT70effxhMSiJyS6PyupLdBx7gicXzP@eEZojU5TEfVc6/Ksw8hy0ImEuoj3MsnUK7zJl1T5X7p8AJog@s/3I8O4ebJfrLhgo0IhQPMZh/50ydvAhSS9xThx6epapI/Ptf4RRLD2ieQcwyxIoDLhs5BDdDMXqt5Jag8e3BEdiIGJUOfdB/sl96mV4H4@Drz99OvNMq6MZYnyoqmwGFfecKl5sBU44/q0I7hWqx6iPUnuhIQTXsHbBtkMePBOgIDzLsvHJLsTaxuMSIAOyjHLZkI0pzRHpb044DZD@IkhQpGGO4mSofSawbt@6r@OLB6b6jvUKFIHZJjY2W0hzbsL22GqU0FE3AfuzacNrezU1GJrp@W7UWGtbDMR6YGAeycVDAX5NNrNy6KPIlYDpi@bBEUAirgiGR56wEVjM0JAX2McghwhZcAnoV1ZncBkjjlEhnFY7HhhCbihK7d3Ic/70cn7nSFu4jEF8ymiu6qCQiiGnZwmCSDSNSvUUzsHwX9v9COacTWPGPQ/lXxP1fD481PaxeRyIgkeE2lX2bt5l7ct6BtQ4/lW3HxH3mOm7z2jSi1sR13cBqm8aw5dc21ms1g6@bBrd9y3rxQvrk1shaRtfRHX2MRLYRWU20v2mQlsGbBtkzjbDVWFcr8GetZl3jgjtsbK4NcusaLzrcreNMij1qmlHTyCyJnzzH8W9RuQvBuOHWY5JcmzroY9mrSvEGq9WkDo7RlQrcuZ2jGmqONj9ywXihhsrk7iBuqvCvLtv9@/fK1bm/7ep7@rbbc/7Y181d2N39Yu0CrOELds1GwzqqNPmm7m/qWqW98Wl7398SN@21s/U8z9fvarW7u7uftEoL2mt@5apy5UVePPb8S/8SR2zsXYy9oTf0Q9/3xx4dez38eMIP8Urx7Y1xyLz@2Bt43OOSSOAgGHsBDvp4HchHfWRygW/meZK3FBF7ka9enmeedS2tcrKmVc73zm80tVXTpNhumrrfGTf6Dd3CaDZ3LHSKvwGWZZueDO9N68z0rb09c3vLare3G/i8anau8XNrycuJaZ1atzgoPxZUK5vb5qvazvTdem5VpAo3Lbflu43N1ri1c3KyZ9T2a/Y@vlrt2t709rrSrjm27Zyeulq3@@7g@KDbbfkV19UqTsfR/Ya@1tR0fMmpVo8OGF/DkVGVoLgqyewNsSnWtJb8RwkLG05JakVfOa2oFqDhy/lWpbQA@C/RLEhbcz/yO63y6hk20azx7Hztxr/Zxua6Wm1sIac2lhFovKwYPDzrnnWdL41GY2dnx601Np7v643t/wE)

For the languages that aren't supported by the above test driver:

- V can no longer test the full polyglot in Tio because it takes too long to run now. But I have added a test to the above test driver to run all code after ␛dgg in the polyglot since these V commands essentially invalidate all prior code.
- Reng can be tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/), and outputs 19 as expected.
- Modular SNUSP can be tested [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html), and outputs 31 as expected.
- Incident was confirmed to output 33 by ais523.

### Explanation

I too have been planning! I have long been stymied by the limitation of starting every line with a `#` or exposing the code to Python, Ruby, and Perl. Well no more! I decided to rip a literal hole in the code. (I use the term *literal* figuratively.) We're now including a literal string from the perspective of the scripting languages, so that we can begin lines with characters other than `#` which Rail, takes advantage of.

#### Kill Perl

The first problem was that Perl 5 didn't want to execute when there was an unsigned string, so after some experimentation, I settled on killing Perl 5's execution after the big print statement. This is handled with `__DATA__=1`. This is followed by `#` to comment out Thutu's `//`. You'll see these in the solution wherever there is a line that doesn't start with a `#`. They seemed to make Thutu happy.

The `DATA` in this statement created two other consequences as well. First, we were using `T` as our Trigger jump label, so that got changed to a quirky `Q` in first line's `: ::Q` and the last line's `Q222999`. Second, Fission treats `UDL` and `R` as starting points and the `D` in `DATA` kicked off another fission reaction heading in the down direction. So, I had to kill the 3rd line's Fission statement `R"12";` and create the line `#.\."12"␉;` to make sure the reactor didn't melt down.  The `\` redirects Fission's code path along the line and the `.`'s are just for spacing.

#### Let's Get Literal

Both Python flavors use `"""` to denote the beginning and end of literal strings. Ruby naively thinks `"` denotes a literal string and has no problem with multiple literal strings bumping up against each other and not being used. But Ruby, Perl, and Pip just could not all agree on when the stuff in between the starting and ending lines for the literal string where actually strings. I settled on letting Pip and Python agree and letting Ruby think what's in between is code. So, this line `""""#//` and this line `"""#"#//` begin and end the string from Python's perspective. Ruby ended up going to a multi-line comment syntax in the middle of all this business with the `=begin    //` and `=end   #//` statements.

#### Reng Around the Rosie

With all the extra `#`'s floating around, Reng had all kinds of problems, so it's code got moved to the bottom and I golf'd out the extra `x` in the Whirl-Incident capsule. At this point, I believe the only 2D lang to traverse the literal string's space is Cardinal and it can be moved into and bound within the literal zone, but I didn't have the byte count to accomplish this today. Next time.

#### Ride The Rail

Rail starts at the `$` in `$'main'//` and continues heading right on the next line starting with the `-`in `#-3o4o␉`. The `$'main'//` line is pretty flexible for inter mixing other code, so it's a good place to add onto.

### The Literal Zone

New lines can be added now above or below the Rail code with a few stipulations:

- Lines need to be added in pairs for Retina to keep working.
- Lines not starting with a `#` are exposed to Thutu but have generally worked for me if I end the statement with `//`
- Code before a `#` is still exposed to Brain-Flak, so `(){}[]` and `<>` may cause problems.
- Every other line should have a literal tab for Whitespace. Or, if this pattern has to be broken, a triple space will usually work.

### Incidental Edit

Incident required a few alterations. `$` and `nd` turned out to be new tokens after the refactor, so I added an extra set of both of these tokens near the end so they no longer counted. The Hexagony module needed to be nearer the end than Incident's final jump token wanted to be placed as a copy of the end of the module, so I had replaced the final jump token with `^_` which all appear before hexagony. Finally, I believe a `[` got pushed to the other side of the bulk of incident's code Incident's which I believe caused the center token to be changed. AIS523 pointed out that an extra set could probably be added safely around the Modular SNUSP code, which worked out nicely and let us meet the byte count, just barely.

Comment: Fails in Incident due to adding a lot of new strings that are repeated three times after the Incident code; the control flow in the Incident program is still correct, but there's no longer an `0o` in the centre of the program (the centre of the program in tokens, as seen by Incident, comes rather later). This seems fixable, however.

Comment: Dangit, I was going to add Cubix as 34, which would only require a carefully placed `QO@`...

Comment: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mzwr.png) how the code looks in Incident at the moment, to help you fix it. The centre of the program, measured in tokens, is currently the second `0g` (all three `0g` are underlined in the screenshot). It needs to be an `0o`; the one three tokens earlier looks promising, but means you'll need to break up some of the tokens later in your program.

Comment: @ais523 Ok, I may not have understood Incident before. I believe if I add the offending tokens a fourth time, they will cease to be valid for Incident. So I have added another copy of `$` and `nd` in a safe spot and changed the final jump token to make Hexagony work. Would you mind verifying again?

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks for the Retina catch. Not sure when I busted that in the refactor, but looks good now. I bet you could work in Cubix still btw. ;)

Comment: It still doesn't work, due to more stray tokens; the easiest fix I've found is to add an additional `[` and `]` (each of which currently appears three times). I placed them around the SNUSP code; no idea if that breaks anything else.

Comment: @ais523 Thanks again. That looked like a good fix for everything else. I had to reduce the second Incident jump code to 2 characters to meet the byte limit. We might need something that identifies Incident's tokens and specifically the center token for testing purposes.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Incident now. I agree that an Incident syntax highlighter would be useful here (there's one as part of the Incident distribution, but that's not really usable online). I know Martin Ender was considering starting a challenge about writing one; I wonder what the progress on that is like.

Comment: @ais523 I added an test to the Polyglot test driver for handling V. Since V seemingly can no longer execute the full polyglot online I'm attempting to only send the code that appears after ␛dgg which I believe invalidate any prior code in V. It's not an ideal solution, but it is better than nothing I think.

Answer (score 12):

## 56. [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), 1286 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPX (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ ']56pq[' ];#//
'(p(x0 \';case $argv[1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 54;;esac;exit;0';print((eval("2\x2f5")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'\{0}1{0}1{0}1{0}([9]<((((((1)(1)(1))){1}1{1}))0{1}1{1})1>0)5{(<{1}(({1}){1})>0)}{0}({1}(1))'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///^_^_X222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkufGL9QlDbIMgCQ2UpQlg6BF23KPqsoljSW7@pmkJBBIkrCwGYtESabfXGfeHPrelzn2f/R1vqJ/pCYiE1wkUa6qQ783lEkmMjOWjDUj6F8r@CJHcXA9CeKc5DTLiZf6lzTVyMtrsuf4WbvZEgS2K429wvWjCcmnlPhRUuRk7Ac0E1wnJ12SlFg0HJAKSanj8W3COE4JgpDwIiA@cZOEjAJnqrkk8NneLA5xPadpklL4zEhEqUeyhLr@2HcZHUJnOY0yP44yjfjuBbnyg4B4NACAFXG3AchIka1NcVKa4MUCgZeb3GN1@VSlsCeii@PSxEnZcWOSsLMvTn2VOkkCTAoVcgyM535IM@LnUkaok/koQwDJaOQxSSVL6cbEidZPSS59hzjAb5Ey3BlNcziexvCSKU0poHSQ@CR1QiJfpX4OIkBB9sgRdVJyklKqABVQAM1cJwE@7pAEYjFSyPEgGlNUpyPtH76RQGEcQnOSXKikrZN//0FwiGaT6pkFb1sULWH/59fktjrAMXAByECpSSo7CrG/kkwfDCi8Z@ZIn6RzAbAKIJWA6HGS64DZSXNgbzVSL5taEqyRJZ17mlgzIr7LA12Qg4h8aLBzuUWaUuBiJVLnAo4cxNEEpAlHTYsIpRGRbQMU4MaRlzUIvQSZxRHXUHzF5Hsy9UFlGSrEGYF4HBclzx2AiRNcACyvlOeCbhYHBdsHkFmO5gcyAVDEeDAmH8jY8QMEgXVExblOaVYEOcIUkYd6D/2IehpZsOHGHm4K40sg5wBSNgE@E655GmMKNoMaYnZUXPrnX//mTSaAp@e6ceqVxvqBeLFbhMCww5h1wBDRXOPICRhbsK@B1Dk4ELh0At9zciQfXZckGBOM6lVcBB6JgWB65YNjTZ1LcMbxmLo55SYeFznw2CChc8Hjg8/tFg4eOiNQLCPAaLNjq2TvFWjJpdxg1LDIxztETfaJlOmn8ovn8osnAwq8KZpSq@r6xAJr02psCp6kbxnOh95Kn2g9J36MXhQk0wJiBqxEWQLRJEVhug4cJ8OgkkPMa5AREzSLRGDozEWvqJRSMgK/XhyM2Qi3AYRX0W9LDCudLvbdNTHqrVkYWCcYWZ49CBJBfAWEGW8YOMGmIyTuTBwglZcH6vEDcYps5u7RLiKwdMQ2omRHHfmgHbQDCDWlMtbOCNtbTb4HsHHtrTlF6FwDFpeH6JUmiT8GJYdgt@k1cSk6A3gF5XEOiRTMMDIf7CgeE0Ntttu/ofw81XvqR91Rb/Rv6hgPf0/NPTKmVyRwoknhTMCQ4whAHNelSV56EJwky8FH7odBNqmWMV3LpkJ17z5tFtvKaL9GA6MP114ZoR00exBUCKJWA/By4qQT5onE81Pwl@D6PnXYcHmPuHiOW@4wcC4@wsIiMYGR0Rl1ixzcDQz5auq7U7Bd5C7iDsuj433yMLVOHUKOOl6SRmbM7tOmoOnLKWTjURQqavQhHoj6iKp7Z4Ipf33i25idLNyAOF6yCBFqbVbTHQ1srxQaZPNjvElA@FukbuZZy@vFUp4g4B8wMaX0cwEKA3v2JxFucaJl2l@LjH4WSZAq/MwHqWMCR1s/OTjEfPAL5XcYkDvPZevBPIYbDYCXCRoXFkoQqDuNiRoRqeRBFlk@/QRs6VnqsoG6dokQFQ3kJKO82NIC0Sd@L7ufUEn34T5GUmqQvigOG5DDggxMKCqCAB6KiLmYTJVbsDWXZpkGDgOy1fA2AtyJdarM727Mp2l8RehcsaRN5P6gQl4VI3/2/1AjLvLFP@FUa2pgU79HDw82/osV8YAeqOIggswFMf2GpZgIQ2YRFoGT81uGGxcg56U6IN04tsE1eAIy@gluXuQnHxPiGO5pq/s7u/LP8KY6EMTkOp/GUetuSBNXK01@Zfygh5DhtOR6czIX11ExgLd@dBEjb3q4GJ0Zmtm@gwJKjoeQYz@bso87Wx@w9XCFQWfhaMw@NmyI0BTvWTxbCOMo5sRBQn7k6O/YlwZhexMHd6PjHfIvKeh4QtXdlj7yI31Ex4/tfPPy5QHbMx6N/Mc2gRiwqFp8b9iWFqNNUoJL0fRB9iR35HxSpHmgenqO3/R//8MDeT/UxtS5zuAafbEcnEX0CjWjjh9VTgmKD@xjsyI/FQGUWL@Bw3Xw6uwEy8FmXM/JOwrWDpeciFVWwGkQgCODyCDAPDRn8ISg8OjiezNSJsO7SZhDR36ogi1vawZTIDzixQKvd49huXeT4Giw4kiD2PF0XgP6dKVRLns6cyZxdK2vpRQtHf0OVhfJnqyKvnxa5AX/xErvt3TnJ/j@lguWO41276W5X349sh@Y2H7MdrnbpBBd1DeBc6GPcHg2huHmo/LDpP4EysrF92PbfjlOHJfqVxl@bTSbt3BFC6BYP/75/fHRN@2HIYS7Wxrwz43oDiIXklqU/zYmOGXAPv6I4TE7cJ0ArK/FbQ97LeqamPx7gg2c0TU2B6Z/3IaQ6qReJ2q8qoBWrZwkeRzIdTcD8WYPg3NjqFHpb2UdSB1@CMdtemvDR23Cj9VVnZVxQxpjYbkh9jiXDlHdwMnANPJSuvQStME@vmWqmCFctJnV6FuGeo@pRa37WLm0gkx8N4bsnTA140MAD48ltfu3hxUabOKxjxUoPpX2@po6Hqbar9802NjNsUp5xGR@RzTiBQKWYGt2ocWPCc2Nr/D9aIqfxpeUf27OQjcbufod0UYNmEnAJfchuLdhEq9a71hba1lnZo2yGwdzflp2X7Jlg7OyWiWRE7LqG8eLW5zFS3w4HPZ1oBT3IKm8j3x2i3bjlBeqvBvCEvg//u6V7a4JzTMS@hlcGCcRNmihGp3GVy843ZJ6L0kcbJchDghjAb9nq696JLvyc3fKu1wg@/dvTnbKFkXZLIaHI8wma1zwc8PSGHhwcsqqac6NF1NuUSXhJdTiUGDQRRiRK9/Lp3B3PfYjl7IWyKIsB05S3BblaYwW2SAHxKMYX1mZ8KmAm20QxxesOkFO/vF33piBRUAGXMN4QZ51CtcoErAFk3VDXH6NXiC5oWlcbpFRyOCWBUjkGvyB8nmFuFOHdYxSjaiLfgmS4T2TV71jou4TCfvc2D6x/LFc7b3784e@MbS/klCHu5aOhQKTm/i9@szMxAZZbLHmFEqL9WUDllerEhGrM7E8FvZUWQtxaVTc4IiMY6auRf8jZO1YZnf0ivU/WJMrwqiDfU4ox7IcHhWGmvdF7aoMl7QQKi/1OCdt/DGAgkhgxBu4BNvrWMsjSHVGvpAp2orqErNtwBMXSIDto9BeXY3XqxH9NR0VLIdfNrVmy2bHqZ7ZnS4bpdSLscHYPx1cDfVsIZXBYPa90ZyB2OIUtj/V0XP2f359W9W6xpcvmXNNRHEuWaxoE5@LpHp7dHC0f3zSO3l/DGKcK6UAj8rOOesCO@WvAmDLRbbwzFJ@@AMCa@KwHwEQmOGuclCO7QCtjvnAwp2BwlrRpnFrlGWnXleUtd8z9mcQ/8Fosa/M@sLCgrO47HoutAhOOuWlONTnSzvMllU1HmGMXhSAIrBsZFefDDVBUOka6QUZWL3ngRpH1znlVSQvpJfVtFghVUdbnqJBRAH3ZvbD7hdo@QrSvXvOgatsH8OcbWogD6j@z7/@jTeNBzmM/7Mcj2H833x8qqOUHnYZOY9L0aBYPhwckQxCCz946MzWzsRLZLDvqKDED0GCl0wguJ0zuzrvCo/c/wDyBCWAMNFM0TIZPZoO5WmeJ891HYPxJA7GGiuI6Az0AIatQQ2gfy6whw/OpG@3t7dMuG9T9XKBkLWGJng75wgV5TkRiXDpJ/b5yCWdToeIGVzvqL1tcUHqVee0JZ4vGa3CXoHH7T4BGABZQcBatwSTq07dVBCU2DaRTIkMLQjJXC/g1TIbwBYFp6NSHiKEjbgUFTY36CwnYM3p9SIfQTKAQjlEObFfchaIVEDEcSui8MB2gV9YYVdw/06u1NbVIP6C29iF/bm4yXQIWMj/bLCcCMb/xcf9gaF@HW76FWJpO72HPzbI938qwLOQveMoxqrsDfBK5KbebOnmtrLmJ2KJCrhFr/gCKMEPwK9c6n@Kk6z3av/gh8Oj4wfNcrZTur9NIlK3Ux@oWqM/XA6kDTa/rDFO4gvg@BtdYzXHHf7Nev/YL6GxOdvs6h691LGJJWj6YgXyi9y5w7HCO9xrR1/wAPZbzlRNEYivCLrCg1vgOjeLImFJdB3y4ZkX4Q/spyyKwSTxl0rsQUKO8IGTvR9pFNFrIoN3hQ4YrVNAKZEqjcVP5Y3ljxtrJ/m3ssa@b3P70m0Qg2dVdYtlI2sO5nU@IIN8MB5EaGPWtf6drunWrVwN7GsdwoLSlatT26y3avV6NarJ1Qgd4@lTTGLzKvjdmSZq4gw2qdVAsSDag5/a1ciqOh256tnNGoOAR8gPtwDwNdO126oz16tPwcwbMJNSjCZUrmYK3lgMTTPnwN@n2I@qeiN0kltZJOIMfyNC8lW/XkcetOoZMvBVHxzXgXPwmmOdpU2rDLf6JLRYVJLuGuuvv1bMbUJEed5sPdlTAHlL12uXg9d7ltR3xk3tszuUKopobolWtCVU9No5Obo4OvoLuExTORb7T@TuM/Ks1rC2d2oNADIbe3@CFzmSpHZLOj6VPguV7p9Ajd3W9pM9GJx3zoVKZ1jv9LWuOuz2hcqtULmZCxWhYs867@r46r/u1vlrv/cTfHbUYT85@mm/d7zfaHbUSvP1YaN5/P5lxYSH9vIJl1rw9G6/9/rw/UmjyUH@fPBh//3Rm94r3/eTzPMyL54Ou3VNVYmqke6wv3W4fbgnVGbf17t1O89z8vGsBpb3ujt7r6sdoP@TUHmH@1V1oGjd4Reh0q/0QWTzphEYl8bMvDAv3saHq3@Hh7Dgz4xPcWpMjanpmaY5M@h743pmXBthfGh68E3hzwhh6BvjmTExIiMyzTt4Hv8XHsZvD2NAFQNYPjNyxGqM4XtyePgWkI2B8Cf48w3DAP6MyxlwGpjsdXqmGHgxmXWq9b26ugcvu1vvlF8vKh6TjgbnFPpEGra3k899TDEVXRckOZFnBhlIFruMV7H11TeH6Lo1s6Ywr2sblrUYblkWzRzXojM/twyJW6Es00snkMXmYNYct0UFsru8q4C/mC1FUWUDs/2Wcmp2OvJ2W@l25e2mAsuiNBPjVBrcGnNz7S33d4cdmb1Mhf9TlFsT1sy5ohiLkdk1lPat3IGxLOMEvmFujihwEsCkyryCASYiW20Fkh9Vvui2qTe37JmxtS3v1HfLP/uJogtnZ697J72zM9usIGsgnYpmvRPNpiiheC28dccB1QJIMa1dQYQXitAe0QlQwO1ZRuEVHjm0oPSqKK7o8vUKSr1Pn5ykBqHH0jBSNpu7O@2d3VZzp7Gzu7PVNrfb7YbZbJjPdp7tGg3TMHfM7Z32rtnY2dptbW1t7cJqe/eZXhMqHh1jTZCQDIJwPJYSSTVfiK0duDy3nolCBQI1dko72FOOtWlXwN8DiEwUvaajb4rnFXEg1fRbLHchBivWXK9J4rkoAPZO97ay3Z7jgeaCh32MrV08KLi2Oe90YVSVEJ@Ec2or3oor1WoVwsC7rtgSDzXBxv@wgxAoISYjQFTJvsRt82v0g1V5nkitLWlgV3ghJJvPlEq3@UyDQqAy5JPyFswNK8zomiZKNtv5zptM/OZ35PyL@WW7quuS1GwTYm6jSE/PTs/@0gSR7u6Kze1fdf1bKRhWl2loTCFCF@GmPNRL/bcOXsOjZS6CwdsC0t5SwgRFHPgjlPGdOS729Sn2H4dgTkC@UH4yDsDh3AarDUiNOd9QIbes8PDHRMZVuJGYvADipV5epBExLIFvwu6ltRwCFbQIYuMGnMS0I/u2aRG/g8jgG7JVSQFfC4i6jcOARjLjwh8q1nLPkpMuQK/xsgZfr/Ptc84WP48bevzYfG35COyF2Ldw5RJaubcBaj7YIw0gwAi/@xhwsZKXGBrkDx/jHjwkZmVxJsbCarGcX6liLtTyRmgJeOxaYgk/yq5yixcG62v49Kl7mvTDoaWEdo7f9XpozYUL2edbarkd2qppJcCslffrdX9oh8qPcsKYD20DNgNtxJwpt0tNR3aprkxp3PQj9Ws0bLzpR3Vz2CgatY/2TcOxjcYM3iC2RtD4DMJbiFLO7Zt6ZDkdeOPd5Y4kEjurO9adKQS5kAP7pu8MbUOxAgCs19/AYYDPrB/U60MFiAew@BDQCp4@depBd2YFqqrgrtPWizf9HAbDuo3Pz2WnM3tx0y8A/rkM3zaQCRRgHuDu6gDwAX8WyJirb8U653GG7M2AvdC2ax9f1D7W7CdPbvozNRw2uPifGyvFI/MzZH7dRuTax3XDYiJhfQxZ/N5//r1Wy4jYAOsDITeSNUjOYe0jrCQrb5j/Hw)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .007322 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1355 bytes)

## Rundown

This program prints **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages (including the most recent addition, dc) were tested via the use of the test driver on TIO, linked above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 by running the official interpreter locally.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program; the remaining output is the output of the program.

### Explanation

#### dc

dc is a fairly old programming language. It originally started as a calculator program, then ended up being given a bunch of stack manipulation commands, and the ability to place functions on the stack, making it Turing complete (in a way rather close to Underload). It was originally intended as a practical language – in fact, it was the first programming language that could be run on the PDP-11 machine that was later used to develop UNIX – but more recently, many people would consider it an esolang. It's also a fairly popular choice for answering challenges here on PPCG, despite being fairly obscure nowadays.

In this case, there are a few relevant properties of dc that make it easy to work into a polyglot: `#` comments; `[…]` string literals; and a quit command `q`. So the program that runs is simply `[…]56pq`, i.e. push a string literal (that we never look at), print 56, then quit.

#### bash, zsh, Perl, Python, Ruby

The dc line is a new line, and it comes before the existing scripting language code. As such, it needs to be harmless in all those languages.

In Perl, Python, and Ruby, `[…]` is a list literal. Placing a string literal inside this allows us to hide the code from these languages, while allowing dc to see it. Single quotes are much better for this purpose than double quotes (single quotes are only used in the polyglot at present to skip small sections of code, whereas several languages have almost the whole thing in a double-quoted literal). We also need a semicolon to discard the list literal when we're done.

In bash and zsh, `[` is a command that evaluates expressions (and for balance's sake, uses `]` to terminate the command rather than `;`). If the first parameter seen doesn't start with `-` (it doesn't), this is a test for nonemptiness, which is great as we can meaningfully apply it to pretty much any string.

#### Thutu

Adding a new line that doesn't start with a `#` means it need to be made Thutu-safe. Appending `//` is the typical way to do this, and works. I also needed to add a `#` to hide it from the scripting languages.

#### Retina

Retina ascribes a different meaning to odd lines and to even lines. I added a line with just `#` in order to get the parity right.

#### Brainf***, self-modifying and otherwise

`dc` has no need to reopen a string literal after its `q`. However, square brackets need to match for another reason: they're loops in Brainf***. We can fix this by putting in an opening square bracket in at the point just between the `q` (where `dc` stops reading) and the `'` (where the scripting languages start).

#### Alphuck

`p`, `dc`'s print instruction, starts a loop in Alphuck. I changed a `p` on the next line to an `x` in order to rebalance the Alphuck code.

#### Incident

As usual. The rebalancing here was accomplished by adding a filler character to the Modular SNUSP line to break up one copy of the `#<` token (this rebalance was more awkward than usual as I needed to break up a token which had copies *before* the main body of the Incident code).

### Summary

This was actually a really easy add (as can be seen by the small size increase). The difference in literal syntax between dc and the scripting languages made it possible to split it off early and safely (this is the same technique that's normally used to include Lua in polyglots, but Lua doesn't have `#` comments; dc does). A lot of languages needed changing, but most of the changes were really minor.

Answer (score 12):

## 61. [S.I.L.O.S.](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 1445 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//`"`   ['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++  L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_00)
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#//
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(( {}){})>)}{}({}()) li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"|/=1/24=x'/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log +39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#*/{puts(p);}/* 
#
/*
1=61 //
printInt 1//
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.s
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax
#sss8␛dggi2␛`|$//''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X2229996
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkmfzF/pSBtkGQBIvUpIlgaBF29Ksuu2W1pLdDpO0XASLJCy8DIASZZmOve7GHuY@lz3Of8x1v2J@pDezCnyJlO2O2I1YSgILqKzMrHxWJvRHET/kNPJvhn6UkYylGekn3hVLdPL0hhxQL92u1QsFDpVE/bHrhUOSjRjxwnickYHns7Tg0ow0SZxj0XFAiiRhtC/ACoMoIbiEBJc@8Ygbx6Tn05HuEt/jsGkU4HzGkjhhcE1JyFifpDFzvYHncjqETTIWpl4Upjrx3Ety7fk@6TMfFiyIu1VARsbp0iNBSi/0owKBjxvfYXV@V2IAE7LZdllME77diMR877NdXyc0joHJQpGcAeOZF7CUeJmcEkZTD2UIS1IW9rmk4rl0I0LD5V2SK48SCvyOE447ZUkG29M5XjJiCQOUFIkPExoQ5TrxMhABCrJFThlNyHnCmApUQAEsdWkMfKyQBGIRUshwIzpXVKMhH54cyaAwsUKncVYoJvXzf/2lQInukNKFDX@OJNmFw9@ek9tSB8fABSADpcaJQlXifCWp0ekw@JtYPWOYTAuAtQBS8YkRxZkBmGmSAXuLkXZV02N/iSxp3NHEkhEJqD7oghyH5E2V78sdJwkDLhYipZewZT8KhyBN2GoyDlEaIdkxQQFuFPbTKmFXILMoFBqKrrl8z0ceqCxFhdAeiIe6KHnhAFyc4AJgebk8Z3TTyB9zOFiZZmh@IBNYihiPB@QNGVDPxyUwj6gE1wlLx36Ga8ZhH/UeeCHr62TGhhv1ESiIroAcBaT8AfhMsORpnCkABjVEfKs49c@//q0/HAKelutGST831jekH7njABimnFkKhojmGoXU52wBXBWpi@VA4Ir6Xp9mSD68yUlwJjjV62js90kEBJNrDxxrRK/AGQcD5mZMmHg0zoDHKgnopYgPnrBb2HhAe6BYToDT5tvWyMEz0JLLhMFowTgb7BItPiRyarxXnuwrTx52GPCm6mq5ZBhDG6xNL/NHcCd/y3DetBb6ROs59yL0Ij8ejSFmwEyYxhBNEhSmS2E7KQaVDGJelfS4oHkkAkPnLnrN5ISRHvj1bGPcRoQN4HoN/TbHsNDpDG7VxFh/ycLAOsHIsnQtSPjRNRDmvGHgBJsOkTgdUiCV5RtqiQ0JivzJ6tYuQ7B0xNZjZFfreaAdtAMINbkylvYI4PWagAFsQntLThHQG8DiihC90CTxBqDkAOw2uSEuQ2cAr2AiziGRMTeM1AM7igbE1Grb299RfpYYLe2dQbXPxjd1jJu/o@YWGbBr4tNwOKZDMOQohCXUdVmc5R4EO0kz8JG7YZA/1PKYrqejQungLm0e2/Jov0QDo4/QXh6hKZo9CCoAUWs@eDmhyZB7Iul7CfiLf3OXOgBc3SEufUCQFQY@SPewMEtMYGRswtxxBu4Ghnw98twR2C5yFwqHFdHxLnl4tEwdQo42mJNGZqzmo1pBN@aPkI17UWio0XU8EPURVXPlAVf@8oNvY6ZpsAFxNGcRItTSU92gOtheLjTI5md4koDwN0vd3LPmx4u5PEHAv2BiStinMSgM7NkbhghCw3naX4qMXhrKkCq81AOpYwJHWz8/PsF88DsTZxiQu8hly8E8ghMNLM8TNE7MlFBg7igiWkjknAdF4vn0I7BlpInLB9rSIUJSdZCTgvLiUzNEH8W57G5CJc11OE5SrpK2JHWrkMP8FEwoHPs@3IxD7mIKU2/B1lyWpjo4DMhWx9MIcCdVmDpdBcxGSXRN2FS15U3k/qRCno173uT/oUZc5EtcYVdLauCPfkQPa4AzRUhSLro1CCG8c2DvBRx6yAsPc9EAjkiLozM/bU/wkNgpSPFNNorC@mo0kRYzNXFae2MEkFz0@GZzHpWWUfEFL73wMkItGcFsdGHq1vYKCjjtr68ceOmIX1ZA19han@Gr06A34JcNACFawR1j4xNBFEaCOEjIC6nxin/pEDE3cbAamFbIP2Vg50Om7dWNnhcaPTa4D/Lo6dNjDjPo9bz7gEAMWM/MvjeAJePeJinBeWS0lrjIipzPx0nma30jw2/23//WB3mva2NEb1I4wV7OBxchu0bNaIN7lZMvxRt@2azIj2Mfqpvv4HApnlqpPx9sxrVPXjGwdjhfhLyoAU59H3wIRAa@vW7O4An@uM9m35uRchmu5j@xOvQCDWx5Rze5AuEWczqerO7DcieJCzR42E/8iPYNUX55bKFRIXs2ocMovDGWorme9H6A1VmeJYt6KxuNs7G4YpH1Pd15Mf59ywVzSHO79dQ6zL/ugQcmdu6zXeE2CUQX7cinl0YPhxcDGG7eqthM4g2hopt93wf2@1lMXWZcp/i10WxewunIhzr57LfXZ6fftB@OEI5NiS@uG9Edhy7kkzD7PibYpc8vf8bwuB241AfrqwvbwzaHtiQm745gfdq7wbp89OdtCKkOKxWiRYviY9FFieP7F7nu5kWiz8LXuRGUh@x7WQdShxfAdmv9peG9NuFF2qLESYUhDbCm2xB76BUlmuvTFEwjy6XLrkAb/PItU8UM4aLNLEbfMtQ7TM3KzPsqlcXK2HMjyN4xVzPe@HBzX1K7ewxYoMH@Gb8sluJdbq/PGe1jqv36TYON3AwLhHtM5geikTibY/WzZBd6dJ/Q3Oga/@5N8aPoionr5iz0eSNXPxBtNJ@bBJwv15f33e9Z6@9eCrEGLpuj4OVGrjLX3/gcQ1OUQHGWkppuflM9G435TD/WX@gn@hk58/woXafAz4mveDtsXp@m1byLB8@8JO/apPPGaBHCW8J4tTo7f5Mi1tDjANwgixKdcDhFoZWKqhbEIhToMASwGRRvTmF/QPS9UgKWnXFYb0DabVK6neyb@9aUOETal0i3K7DySvVwEvOu0iuxtF2iXackv30rl@ROuE9MmYMyKFA2g9IVuIHHvwSfi62TkAa8JYHj2U5t0fcAs8Nm1wgKeEj3r0OPlxZulIjqXbSI@NHqH3/v5z3AIYNNBl5KfRAEdq2hRB9F108E3Zx6K44p9hARByQYXxQf2rMWSa@9zB2J1h94xeuj8928b5N30OHmFPP8EhdCqTA1AB5oJpQmuOlHTBhTTni@arYpCDXjICTXXj8bpTrYT@gy3hea9SqAkwTBwiyJ0Bir5Jj0GWY@Xjt9HINu/Si65CUbcvKPv4tuFUx6aEI4npHn7dMligS81OItIteNxsD1DMlnlkQ5iIJChoA5BoncgCsw8Vwl7ojyNhpYojZrIiEZ0Uh61joj2iGRsfmPPSXbGyil1qu/vGmbXecrCQw4BRtYxnK5ST9rj61UqpIZiD1Fu1qeNmF6MSsTqTSR8m1ho5n3VedGJbyJKDjm6po1hQLeo@Z2x655U4h3/kLMB9j8hRo1zeBW5aiF0zglBY7PAZSj2llGtvENCQORwEh0tQm@c8AGBy4pTcgXMkJb0VxibZtwJwTiY08tcBZFy3KdaDxnvTE/XV3V9Frd4dspXTiNJh8lrB9h17X9vnPdNdKZVDqdyc9mbQJiixIAf2Sg5xz@9vy2pDfNL19SegPF61S2eSWL7l26PT0@PTw7b52/PgMxTsUui0dREtBFiEAjiH04xY0in7exQR6JB@X/d8PGPHTkgpPevpVKYpzHAJIHKnLKdZWrRU6Xg1R1pj7cOnjUGKLijDSo/XZDsOHMSMQBdt4CO6vMzO9yJIpCSpQ0iGUSVV2d5fBCXE/gQ0BkS@zPPjzkLaA2A@FeBXDOt4ARTG7cxPR/ifPT1tnZ9zlHqO9xDsCF71FfInzUOn6xTniJJgKszeeJAb4W7/sOJ3BIg/g14JaJXeWZxUT5W4GZQ0O8HolWFfUXISmdd53QhgYYUH3wSTRmXp@k6JQE/V8nLT@FANjvg0f3bjIMCBAJRaNp3m2SirB1fZ6fqkQqIGzqrHeHweGv4UzufhCLSxyOY043vWDpMOOff/2beKnSyWD87/l4AOP/FOP3BgpovQsveJyLBsXy5viUpJBlxMYDOlnaEwZ6TCReOGbEC0CCV1wgCC6YXex3gUdpvwF5ghJAmBixMEhxeizpKqMsi/cNA/PyMPIHOu9asAnoAWKcDoW68WmM77ggrho72ztbFhTFTLuaIeSt0yGW0AKhqu6D/RSuvNj50HNJo9EgUgo1GHN2bCFIo0Tf16UPc0ZLAFsQKbxNYA0sWayAuWa@TCnRiqXiUvQ/2ZJJ14bsLPQCAV7hAwBR8XGYy0OCDBLlosIuLJtkPBjezI4mcC4IIxKgnPibzhkiDRAJ3KpUWLNd4BdmeJ3srZwJ9WU1SL8jGK@q96VNpkPAQv5rg@WEMP4PMW53TO1rd9NburnttNZfxil3X6XhXsjBWRhh6@QIeCVKzajVDWtHXfITKUcF3KJXfAGU4AfgVy7zPkZx2np2ePzLyenZ2sskDinfBZOJ3GxUOppebXfnA/mOzc9E@vTIOHv59GgmyGWu8qm7XG1Cfpexe4j9LnoS66T4xBohy/xRxItiaeNGFqXUEuAzUUWtUVXU22m722h2wuIa@S@b3vQW9TK@3IVRJ@XveWWyIcDMuy7n0SWYxzdeYWkZQnifl19meflqfFNUaxp9dmXgq42CbsxmIDcqjRVuVfG6TchgRh7iRP6kZElAd0HLLayVxMuMzDomc3rLK9e3O0sz4Kd5hxBcH/9jAt@FwLHMA04OfmVhyG6IAlEsoBAc6Bgq1UStzv5lpzp/ybqkzX/JG453fftQvvUjiGAlw@YHQHsKbvyhQzpZZ9AJ0ZftG@MnQzfsW6XkOzcGhF@1qZRGjlWplyuVUlhWSiEGoEeP8Nw4LUF8u9AlXZoAkFbyVRuyKsRDpxTaJdpQSn2nVuYr4BZqyVtY8DU19NsSnRqlRxBOqvAkYRi1mVJKVTwfmrpuTYG/j5EXloxqQONbRSLSBN9VI/mSV6kgD3rpAhn4anTOKty4OmcGP6naeVozhoHNo7@8aqN//FG0dgiRlGmt/vBABeR1wyhfdZ7bcpsOavont3t6eXr6Vi6qkrUl2eFWoWiUzS@PDeMDBHlC2nK3/VBpPn5crto7u@XqgS1b1QPrgfnggWWpSq2mnj1QLHIqy9t1@ey9/KlQbD4ArdZ3Hh48@FAo4s@HBgwa3UqjrTe1brNdKN4Wip@nOOVMGq8q@Gk/b1bEh5AXcG1o3XZ8@uKwdXZYrTW0Yu35SbV29vpp0YKb7fkdTtXh7tVh6/nJ6/NqTSz5y/Gbw9enR61nnufFab@f9qNRt1nRNY1oOml221snOycHheLk50qz4mRZRt5dlMEYnzcnrw2tAfRfFIqvEF7TOqre7H4pFNvFNkhxWjN988qcWJfW5cvoZPF7cgIT3sT8GCXmyBxZfcuyJiZ7bd5MzBsziE6sPnwz@DEDGHrmYGIOzdAMLWsFz/2/wUn08iQCVBEsyyZmhljNAXwPT05eArIBEP4IP55pmsCfeTUBTn2Lf95fmKaKh8JJo1Q5qGgH8HGalUb@9aTY5@LRYaMFOGZ3t3fi2s6nNjZTyPZet80mXtaVSFXutDHpFw2jICuKEndkmzrU5rVyCd8ZtK1upXRL98dT9PayVVa5o26btl1u5eMtGOfDXdtmKXVtxG/LwoYVhV1RX5GszqQ2qEkqnsH2wFusuqopJt5tqe@tRkPZ2VabzZ2aGiWSPJGiRL6dih/ldtpQ@EfFH1XFh/m1qXZulQbAKATu@AOxAuDgLEtGlMjFaRHDUEi2tlU4ijB1a0fZrezlP85DFTBLcl3FH@mL4VhGbcuZyEbh4uJ567x1ceFYRWQJpFTU7VeSVZNkFL6NpXHkM92H5F@p7xUk@KAsnR4bAjmET1MGn@CUsjFj1@PxNZt/nnkp/fiRxpBhDFvH4Fqr7e1u7@7Va7vV3b3drW1rZ3u7atWq1uPdx3tm1TKtXWtnd3vPqu5u7dW3trb2YHZ777FRLhT7bICVe0xSiNvRQI5lzXoi1XehFK0/lgpFiO34pqmB7@QifdQs4PtUohDVKAObZeMWjUOJVXtqlAmYDeC0nB0LN8HVCMdcYsFNo3mL@5oW@tgO3trD/UIEmDaaMCjJiFXGR1o92oqKpVIJgsWrplSXTvS04OC/HOIKFBQXFSAqpl@ibetr@Itd3I/l@pbccYqia6FYj9Vis/ZYh6q92BUPlS141i1ye6tZRTLx/q9@6QTVl@7@1B8OvdpPH75A/pfl2jYh1g7q7KvWEL8NuLy/eH/xtgYK3Nvb@cMwvnU4gNl5lhwwSCDjYFOabCXeS4rVWDhPlTB4OYasPNcmQXX6Xg/1ufJMqHj5Ef//SnhWQL5QSwoOwMfdKi8RSZn7e1clt7PGgoKzWNuq81I4Ydk4CYlpi5YFovDs@RCooPURBwF4/Qp@rniOZROvgcjgG5JpTgE/sxUVB4c@CxXOhddV7cJyjc85acLqJV6W1lcqAnwq2BL7cYO@2LaYm98CewF2Ml0lX63eAWibXYCRO6acb/NHtgFHPmWOoUr@9DburIdzgzrbE2dhMZk/X6hiWihn1cAu4LbLsV34VXHVWzzP2F@DR4/c93E76Npq4GT4XakE9rRwqXgCpJw5gaNZdgzM2lm7UvG6TqD@qsSc@cAxARhoI@ZUvZ1rOnRydaVq9XM71L6G3epRO6xY3eq4Wn7nfK5Sx6xO4A/EVvWrn0B4M1EqmfO5Etq0AX94tFqRROykFWqvtl5gyaXiO5/btOuYqu3DwkrlCDYDfKZtv1LpqkDch8n1hbb/6BGt@M2J7WuailDv60@O2hkMuhUH7/cV2pg8@dwew/p9Bb4dIOOrwDysW9UB4AP@bJCxUN@CdcHjBNmbAHuB45TfPSm/KzsPH35uT7SgWxXi3zcXikfmJ8j8so0o5XfLhsVFwjubivSzt/@zXk6JVAXrAyFX46WVgsPyO5iJF94w/R8)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006366 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1517 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- This has been tested to working Incident by ais523 on the official interpreter.
- Deadfish~ was can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).

### S.I.L.O.S.

At @RohanJhunjhunwala’s suggestion, I looked at adding S.I.L.O.S.. It was a short investigation, because I only had to put a line that said print 61 in somewhere, and it worked. The only problem was Thutu, which required a trailing `//` on each line that didn’t start with a `#`, and when I added this to the end of the print statement, the output became `61//`. So I poked around with the documentation for a minute, and found this:

> 1 = 5
>
> printInt 1
>
> //prints five

Well that’s easy. `1 = 61 //` and `printInt 1//` gets us past Thutu and virtually done. Just a couple tweaks.

### Alphuck

S.I.L.O.S. added a `p`, which is a loop initializer is Alphuck, so I had to add the matching terminator to compile. That Terminator, `s`, got placed at the end of the Minkolang line `#<R>"3"O.s`

### Incident

Incident was slightly imbalanced, so I removed some detokenizing bits from @ais523’s last answer in a guess and check fashion. Now, `#*/{puts(p);}/*` no longer has a trailing space, and `console.log 39` no longer has a `+`.

Edit: Okay, I didn't need to actually do anything with incident, so I just undid all the above detokenizations.

### Test Driver Update

In the past, I've found myself failing to notice that a language was returning a number, but the wrong one. I've finally gotten around to addressing the problem and added a test result to the output of the test driver. so now, when Retina returns 7 instead of 8, the test will be flagged as a fail.

I also did a little formatting for alignment. Languages that aren't on Tio will now have a place holding X's where their numeric result is expected and single digit results will have a place holding space inserted as well.

Comment: Wow +1 because I didn't think anyone would come up with such a clever abuse of the use of integers as variables!!

Comment: Moorhens 2.0 works

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Did you patch my hack? :P This polyglot solution stopped working. https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@29oa2aooK/PVVCUmVfimVeiYKiv//8/AA

Comment: Unfortunately,  the latest change with expression parsing is broken, however [this](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@2@obWaooK/PVVCUmVfimVeiYKiv//8/AA) works

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Oh, thanks! That's an easy swap.

Comment: This doesn't work in whitespace, does it?

Comment: @bearacuda13 Whitespace works for me here: https://pastebin.com/rJZxBXfQ

Answer (score 12):

## 62. Grass, 1617 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//`"`   ['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++  L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.x4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_00)
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#//
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(( {}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"|/=1/24=x'/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log +39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#*/{puts(p);}/* 
#
/*
1=61 //
printInt 1//
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.s
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
#sss8␛dggi2␛`|$//''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X2229996
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkmfjF/pSBtkGQBIvUpIlgaBF29Ksuu2W1pIfYZKWIbBIwsLLAChSlunY627sYe5z2eP8x1z3K@ZHejOrQBIUKbs7YjdiIQkooLIyszKzsjKz9HsJL3Ia@TdDP8pIRtOM9BPvmiYaeXpDDhwv3a43BIFBJVF/7HrhkGQjSrwwHmdk4Pk0FVwnIy0S51g0bJASSajT52DCIEoIDiHBlU884sYxufSdkeYS32OwaRRgf0aTOKFwT0lIaZ@kMXW9gecyOoROMxqmXhSmGvHcKzLxfJ/0qQ8DlsTdGiAj47TwiZPShH4kELjc@A6ri7cyBZiQzqdLYydh041IzOY@n/UkceIYmBRK5AwYz7yApsTLpJRQJ/VQhjAkpWGfSSpeSDciTlicJbn2HOIAv@OE4U5pksH0NIaXjGhCAaWDxIeJExB5kngZiAAF2San1EnIeUKpAlRAATR1nRj4WCEJxCKkkOFENKaoZlM6PDmSQGF8hObEmVBKGuf/@ovgEM0m5QsL/mxRtITD356T23IX28AFIAOlxonsKMT@RlK926XwNzUv9WEyEwCrAFLxiR7FmQ6YnSQD9pYt9bquxX6BLGne0UTBiDhUH3RBjkPypsbm5Y6ThAIXS5E6VzBlPwqHIE2YajIOURoh2TFAAW4U9tMaodcgsyjkGoomTL7nIw9UlqJCnEsQj@Oi5PkCYOKEJQCWl8tzTjeN/DGDg5FphuYHMoGhiPF4QN6QgeP5OAT6ERXnOqHp2M9wzDjso94DL6R9jczZcKM@AgXRNZBzACn7AGsmKKw0xhQAgxoiNlXs@udf/9YfDgFP23WjpJ8b6xvSj9xxAAw7jFkHDBHNNQodn7EFcDWkzocDgWvH9/pOhuTDm5wEY4JRnURjv08iIJhMPFhYI@caFuNgQN2MchOPxhnwWCOBc8X9g8ftFiYeOJegWEaA0WbTVsnBM9CSS7nBqME4G@wSNT4kUqp/kJ/sy08edinwpmhKpazrQwusTauwT/Amfc9w3rSX@kTrOfciXEV@PBqDz4CeMI3BmyQoTNeB6aToVDLweTVyyQTNPBEYOluiEyollFzCup5PjNkItwEcr@K6zTEsdTqHWzUx2i9YGFgnGFmWrjkJP5oAYcYbOk6w6RCJO0MHSGX5hNp8Qpwi@7I6tasQLB2xXVKyq156oB20A3A1uTIKcwTwRp3DADauvcKiCJwbwOJyF73UJPEGoOQA7Da5IS7FxQCrgnI/h0TGzDBSD@woGhBDrW9v/0D5WaK31fe6o37Rv6tjnPwdNbfJgE6I74TDsTMEQ45CGOK4Lo2zfAXBTNIM1shdN8g@qrlP19KRUD64S5v5ttzbF2ig9@Hayz20g2YPggpA1KoPq5w4yZCtRNL3Elgv/s1d6gBwfYe4@BFBVhj4KN7DwnxjAiOjU@qOM1huYMiTkeeOwHaRu5AvWO4d75KHT0Xq4HLUwYI0MmO2HtUFTV98QjbuRaGiRtfxgNdHVK2VD0z5xQ/fx@ykwQbE0YJF8FCFr5ruaGB7udBgNz/DSALc33zrZitrEV4s5AkC/gU3poR@HoPCwJ69YYggTrjY9gue0UtDCbYKL/VA6riBo62fH5/gfvCW8hgG5M73sqIzjyCigeH5Bo0dcyUI1B1FRA2JlPMgi2w//QRs6WnisoZaCCJERQM5ySgv1jVH9InHZXc3VNJah2MkpRrpiGKvBnuYn4IJhWPfh5dxyJaYTJVbsDWXpqkGCwZkq2E0AtyJVarMVgGzURJNCJ0plrSJ3J9UyLPxpTf9f6gRF/nid5hVQQ3s0x/RwxrgXBGimItuDYIL7xzYewFBD3nh4V40gBBpGTqzaHuKQWJXEOObbBSFjVVvIi576jxae6MHsLlo8c3mfVQsomIDXnrhVYRa0oN568LQzO0VFBDtr48ceOmI3VZA19ha72Gj0@BywG4bAEK0gjvGxjqCKIw4cZCQFzr6K/bQwGNu4mDVMa2Qf0rBzodU3Wvol16oX9LBfZBHT58eM5jB5aV3HxCIAfOZ@XMDWDK@3CQliEdGaxsXWZHz@TjJfLWvZ/ik//1vfZD3ujZGzk0KEezVonER0glqRh3cq5x8KL6w22ZFfhr7kN38AIfrYNTq@IvGZlz75BUFa4f4ImRJDXDq@7CGQGSwttfNGVaCP@7T@XMzUibD1f2Pjw69QAVb3tEMpkB4xT0dI6v7sNzZxDkaDPYTP3L6Ok@/PLrUKJc9nTrDKLzRC95cSy7/AKvzfZYs861sNM7G/I5J1o9058X4970lmEMa2@2n5mH@uAcemNi5z3b5sknAu6hHvnOlX2LzYgDNzVPlk0m8IWR08@d9YG/PYsel@iTFx0azeQnRkQ958tlvr89Ov2s/DCGETYnP7xvRHYcu7Cdh9mNMMEuf3f6M4TE7cB0frK/BbQ/LHGpBTN4dwfrO5Q3m5aM/b0NIdVitEjVaJh/LKkoc3z/IdTcP4nUWNs6NID2kP9p1YOvwAphuvV9o3msTXqQuU5yUG9IAc7oNvse5dojq@k4KppHl0qXXoA12@56p4g7hos0sW98z1DtMzdPM@zKV5cjYcyPYvWOmZnzx4eW@Te1uGLBEg/UzdlsOxbfcXp9Tp49b7bfvGmzkZpgg3GMyf8Ab8dgcs5@CXWjRfUJzown@3bvFj6Jryu@bd6EvG7n6A95G9ZlJQHy5Przv/sha33op@Bq4bfaCVxu5ylx/43d0TVECyVlK6prxXfVsNOYz7Vh7oZ1oZ@TM86P0u/KA1DRN@X2jKbOQ8hWrnC1S2bSWF/zgm5fkBZ50UUMtgSdMKEts56E6KWG6PQ5gxWRRohEGJ8tOtaooAh@Esh@GADaHYnUsLCXwEllKYBFkDNYbkE6HlG@n@8a@OSM2EfdF0utxrCypPZzGrAD1ig/tlJ2eXZbevZPKUjfcJ4bEQCnkMptBnRW4gccenM/l1EnoBKx6ge35TC1eIgELxbrYCHJ9iAxehx7LQtwo4Yk@ryaxKOwff@/n5cIhhUkGXur4IAgscEM2P4omTzjdnHo7jh0sNyIO2It8nqeoz9oknXiZO@JVQlhAr4/Od/MST15sh5dTDAkKXHClQtcAeHAyrjTOTT@i3O5ywotR80mBVxoHIZl4/WyUamBqoUtZCWle1gBOEgQLsyRCu62RY9KnuEmyNOvTGHTrR9EVy@6Qk3/8nRe2oNNDE8L2nDyrtBYoEjBgk1WTXDcaA9dzJF9oEuUgMgoZfOsYJHIDq4by7wpxRw6ruIElqvN6E5LhNadn7TOiHhIJzwmw/GR5A7ncfvWXNx2jZ38jgQ4Bs44ZL5Ob@LP62EzFGpmDWDO0q2K3Ad3LXomI5amYTwtr0qwEuzAqvpqIjG2mrnn9KGDlbGZ3dMLqR6xIGOLWgXViSGfTDF4VhpovGrssQ6QdQOaqnmVkGw9TKIgEWrwATvB4AmshOKQ8JV/JCG1FdYm5bcAbF4iP5bfAXuY3xZRSf04vxywQu65r9YbNplO@sJst1kpoP8ICbedDd9LT07lUut3pz0Z9CmKLEgB/pOPKOfzt@W1Zaxlfv6bODeS5M8liSS8u7/Lt6fHp4dl5@/z1GYhxxmdZOoqSwFm6CDSC2IeAbxT5rOIN8kg8mv7YbSxcRy448d07sczbuQ8guaMip0xXuVqktOikanP14dRhRY3BK85Jg9pvNzgbxoxIbGDnHbCzysziLUciy6TskCYxDaIoq70MnovrCVwERFZgf34xl7eE2gyEc@XAOd8chjO5cRKz/yXOT9tnZz/mHKF@xDkACz@iXiB81D5@sU64QBMB1vrzjQEey6PBwynEc@C/BswysQA9t5goP0CYL2jw1yNe1XL8pUtKFwUqtKEBOlQf1iQaM0tlUlyUBNe/Rtp@Cg6w34cVfXmToUMAT8hrUovClFiCqWuL/alGRAFhU3u9kAwLfgLhu/uRDy4zOIY53XQW06X6P//6N37@0s2g/e95ewDt/@TtDzoKaL1gz3lciAbF8ub4lKSwy/CJB860MCd09LiReOGYEi8ACV4zgSA4Z3Y53yUeufMG5AlKAGGix0InxejRpCePsize13Xcl4eRP9BYgYNOQQ/g4zTI6fXPYzwOA7@q72zvbJmQP1P1eo6QVVmHmG1zhIqyD/YjXHux/fHSJc1mk4gppGvU3rG4IPWy86EhflwwWgZYgW/hHQJjYMhyBPS18mFy2amaCg7F9SeZEulZsDtzvYCDl1kDQBT8HObyEGEHiXJRYcGWTjPmDG/moQnEBWFEApQTOxSdI1IBEcetiMKa7QK/0MNSam8lJtSKahDfIhhLwPfFTaZDwEL@a4PlhND@D97udA31W2/Tgd7Cdtrr53by3VM3nAs5OAsjrLIcAa9Eruv1hm7uKIV1IuaogFtcFV8BJawDWFcu9T5Fcdp@dnj8y8np2dq5E4OU7oJJRGo1q11Vq3V6i4Z0x@bnIn16pJ@9fHo0F2SRq7zrLlebkN9l7B5ib3n5Yp0U61gjZBp/FPEyr9o4kWXWVQB8xhOuNaqycjvr9JqtblhaI/9106FwSavgOTC0uik7EpbIBgezKNCcR1dgHt857VIzhPC@FM@9vHw0HirVW3qfXut4CiJo@rwH9ka5ucKtwk/muAzm5MFP5F/Kpgh0l7RcYS17LjIyL64s6BVHrk93vs3AOs2LibD08Z8r8NgEwjIPODn4lYYhvSEyeLHAAefgjCGpTZTa/L97aovz2II2/yWvTd5d24fSrR@BByvrFgsArRks449d0s26g26Ia9m60X/SNd26lcu@faOD@1Vacnlkm9VGpVothxW5HKIDevQI48ZZGfzbhSZq4hSA1LKvWLCrgj@0y6FVdppyuW/XK2wEvEIueQsDvqW6dlt2Znr5EbiTGnxJKHptKpdTBeNDQ9PMGfD3KfLCsl4LnPhWFok4xWNtJF/2qlXkQStfIAPf9O5ZlRlX90xnkaqVb2v6MLCY95dWbfT330vmDiGiPKs3Hh4ogLyh65Xr7nNL6jiDuvbZ7Z1enZ6@k0qKaG6JVrgllPSK8fWxrn8EJ09IR@p1Hsqtx48rNWtnt1I7sCSzdmA@MB48ME1FrteVsweySU4labshnX2QPgul1gPQamPn4cGDj0IJfz42odHsVZsdraX2Wh2hdCuUvsywy542X1Xx6jxvVflFyAu4N9VeJz59cdg@O6zVm2qp/vykVj97/bRkwsv24g27GvD26rD9/OT1ea3Oh/zl@M3h69Oj9jPP8@K030/70ajXqmqqSlSNtHrAwvTnaqtqZ1lG3l9UtOnWyc7JgVB63pq@1tUmMPBCKL3CAaraVbRW76tQ6pQ6IMZZ3fCNa2NqXplXL6OT5e/JCXR4U@NTlBgjY2T2TdOcGvS1cTM1bowgOjH78KTwYwTQ9IzB1BgaoRGa5gqe@3@Dk@jlSQSoIhiWTY0MsRoDeA5PTl4CsgEQ/gQ/nmEYwJ9xPQVOfZNdHy4MQ8GocNosVw@q6gFcdqvazB9PSn0mHw0mKkCc3dveies7nztYTSHbe70OnXpZTyQ1qdvBXb@k64Iky3LclSzHdiyWLJfxfKFj9qrlW2d/PMPlXjErClup24ZlVdp5ewvaeXPXsmjquBbityRuxLJMrx1fFs3utD6oiwoGYXuwXMyGosoGvm0pH8xmU97ZVlqtnboSJaI0FaNEup3xH/l21pTZpeCPouDH/N5SurdyE2BkAm/sAx8BcJO3b9/i39vJ9YS3WIN/e7voLL7gBTEwGTlEKs1K6L5CsrWtQAhDla0debe6l//YDxVgSJQaCv6IX3Xb1Otb9lTShYuL5@3z9sWFbZZwJiDckma9Es26KKHOLEypI59qPgQN1caeIMKFKrAv6RDIIXyaUriCU4eOKZ2MxxO6uJ55qfPpkxPDzqRbGjrlen1vd3t3r1Hfre3u7W5tmzvb2zWzXjMf7z7eM2qmYe6aO7vbe2Ztd2uvsbW1tQe923uP9YpQ6tMBZvwxScHfRwMpllTzidjYhRS28VgUSrAn4GFWE4/9Im3UEvDIlshE0SvAZkW/RZuSY8Wa6RUC1gY4TXvHxEkw7UN4TEx4abZucV4zoY8V5609nC94jlmzBY2yhFgl/KQ2oq2oVC6Xwcm8aokN8URLBRv/qxFHoKCYqABRKf0abZvfwl@s0n4sNbakrl3i1Q7ZfKyUWvXHGmT7pR7/KG/Bt16JmWndLJGp93/1C/nFYFIwtFXj29BYXgsrXLPJQmvD@@Q6QJNJd3/qD4de/aePXyFWkaT6NiHmDtrJN7XJf5tw@3Dx4eJdHYxmb2/nd13/XiADvYsdfUBhsxsHm7b0duK9dDBzDBfbOjRejiGCWFgQQRPyvUu0oZVv3KyKn9i/jcI3AflCy5CxAe7IrbF0llSYa@op5HZeBJGxF/NwZZG2JzQbJyExLF5eQRSetWgCFbR4YiMAy7XBJcmebVrEayIyeMLGn1PAaz6iamPTp6HMuPB6iiUU6xGMkxaMLvBSGF@tcvAZZ4vPxw36fNq8b/EK7AVYdXXlfLRyB6Bj9ABG6hpSPs0/Mg0IT@UFhhr509O4Mx5iHGU@J8bCsjP/vlTFTKhktcAScNqV2BJ@lV3lFmMv61vw6JH7Ie4EPUsJ7Ayf1WpgzYQr2eMglcwObNW0YmDWyjrVqtezA@VXOWbMB7YBwEAbMafK7ULToZ2rK1VqXzqh@i3s1Y46YdXs1ca1ynv7S82xjdoU/kBsNb/2GYQ3F6Wc2V@qoeU04Q/DwBVJxHZadazVMhEMuZJ9@0vH6dmGYvkwsFo9gskAn2nHr1Z7ChD3oXN9oOU/euRU/dbU8lVVQagPjSdHnQwavaqN7/uy05w@@dIZw/h9GZ42kPEVYB7GreoA8AF/FsiYq2/JOudxiuxNgb3Ativvn1TeV@yHD790pmrQq3Hx7xtLxSPzU2S@aCNy5X3RsJhIWBVWFn/29n/WKikRa2B9IORaXBjJOay8h554uRpm/wM)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006780 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1695 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **62** in Grass **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Amazingly the incident tokenizer in the test driver indicated that the tokens had not changed from the last entry, so I did not bother to run this.
- Deadfish~ was can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).

### Explanation

Here is the Grass code:

```
wWWWwWWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
w WWWw WWWWWWWWw WWWWw WWWWWWWw WWWWWWWWwwww v
wWWWwWWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/grass#@18eHh4OwuHlZVzlECaIpQCiQQQYQFhwPpIEECiANWIzBAcLAWDaoCSCRmZh4ZeX/f8PAA)

It was taken from an earlier [answer made by myself and 1000000000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95207/).

## Evil

The first problem with inserting the grass was that evil already had some `w`s in its code which would mess with the grass.  In order to fix this I split the grass code into two sections straddling the evil code.  Now evil had a little bit of a problem with the grass code.  Each `w` in the grass code printed a null character `\x00` so I needed to skip over all the `w`s, this was done easily with a `f` and an `m`.

## Cubix

Cubix once again broke because of the increase in program size so I had to move the capsule.  Moving the Capsule broke cardinal, but I was able to fix it by adding an `x` before the Cubix.

Comment: SILOS has recently had changes, therefore, this was valid with a recent commit, but with the new version, l=61 // doesn't quite work, instead please change it to l+61

Answer (score 12):

## 64. [Agony](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Agony), 1613 bytes

````
#16  "(}+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉11)(22)S␉␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>.}+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsd4O6O@oh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.

#
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts(p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<q>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-}+^_^_X2229996
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006153 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1689 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkmfjF/pSBtkGQBIvUpIlgaRE29Ksuu2W1pIfYZKWQLBIwsLLAChSlunY627sYe5z2eP8x1z3K@ZHejOrQBIUKbs7YjdiIQkooLIys/JVlVn6vYAXOQu926EXpiSlSUr6sXtDY408uyWHtptsV2uCwKDisD923GBI0hElbhCNUzJwPZoIjp2SJokyLBo2SIHE1O5zMGEQxgSHEP/aIy5xooj0PHukOcRzGWwS@tif0jiKKdwTElDaJ0lEHXfgOowOodOUBokbBolGXOeaTFzPI33qwYAlcacCyMg4yX3ipDShHwoELie6x@rirUgBJqDz6dLIjtl0QxKxuc9nPYntKAImhQI5B8ZT16cJcVMpIdROXJQhDElo0GeSihbSDYkd5GdJblyb2MDvOGa4ExqnMD2N4SUjGlNAaSPxYWz7RJ7EbgoiQEG2yBm1Y3IRU6oAFVAATRw7Aj5WSAKxECmkOBGNKapel45OjyVQGB@h2VEqFOLaxb/@IthEa5DipQV/DVG0hKPfXpC7YgfbwAUgA6VGsWwrpPGNJHqnQ@Fvavb0YTwTAKsAUvGIHkapDpjtOAX2li31pqpFXo4sqd/TRM6IOFQfdEFOAvK2wubljOOYAhdLkdrXMGUvDIYgTZhqPA5QGgHZMUABThj0kwqhNyCzMOAaCidMvhcjF1SWoELsHojHdlDy3AGYOMEFwPIyec7pJqE3ZnAwMknR/EAmMBQxngzIWzKwXQ@HQD@i4lzHNBl7KY4ZB33Uu@8GtK@RORtO2EcgP7wBcjYgZR/AZ/ycpzGmABjUELKpYtc///q3/nAIeFqOE8b9zFjfkn7ojH1g2GbM2mCIaK5hYHuMLYCrIHU@HAjc2J7bt1MkH9xmJBgTjOokHHt9EgLBeOKCY43sG3DGwYA6KeUmHo5T4LFCfPuaxweX2y1M3Ld7oFhGgNFm01bJ4XPQkkO5waj@OB3sEjU6IlKif5QP9uWDxx0KvCmaUirq@tACa9NK7BO8Sd8znLetpT7Rei7cEL3Ii0ZjiBnQEyQRRJMYhenYMJ0Eg0oKMa9CekzQLBKBoTMXnVAppqQHfj2fGLMRbgM4XkW/zTAsdTqHWzUx2s9ZGFgnGFmarAUJL5wAYcYbBk6w6QCJ20MbSKXZhFp8Qpwi@7I6tesALB2x9SjZVXsuaAftAEJNpozcHAG8VuUwgI1rL@cUvn0LWBweopeaJO4AlOyD3ca3xKHoDOAVlMc5JDJmhpG4YEfhgBhqdXv7B8pPY72lftBt9Yv@XR3j5O@puUUGdEI8OxiO7SEYchjAENtxaJRmHgQzSVLwkfthkH1Us5iuJSOheHifNottWbTP0cDow7WXRWgbzR4E5YOoVQ@8nNjxkHki6bsx@It3e586ANzcIy5eIcgKA1fiAyzMFyYwMjqlzjgFdwNDnoxcZwS2i9wF3GF5dLxPHj7lqUPIUQcL0siM2XxSFTR98QnZeBCFihpdxwNRH1E1Vz4w5ec/fB@znfgbEIcLFiFC5b5quq2B7WVCg9X8HHcSEP7mSzfzrMX2YiFPEPAvuDDF9PMYFAb27A4DBLGDxbKfi4xuEkiwVLiJC1LHBRxt/eLkFNeDd5TvYUDufC3LB/MQdjQwPFugsWOuBIE6o5CoAZEyHmSRraefgC09iR3WUHObCFHRQE4yyot1zRF94vuy@wsqaa7DMZJShbRFsVuBNcxLwISCsefByzhgLiZT5Q5szaFJooHDgGw13I0Ad2KZKrNVwHQUhxNCZ4olbSL3JxXyfNxzp/8PNeIgX/wOs8qpgX36I3pYA5wrQhQz0a1BcOFdAHsvYdNDXrq4Fg1gi7TcOrPd9hQ3iR1BjG7TURjUVqOJuOyp8t3aW92HxUWLbjevo2IeFRvwyg2uQ9SS7s9bl4Zmbq@ggN3@@siBm4zYbQV0ja31HjY68XsDdtsAEKAV3DM21uGHQciJg4TcwNZfs4cGEXMTB6uBaYX8Mwp2PqTqXk3vuYHeo4OHII@fPTthMINez30ICMSA@cz8uQEsHvc2SQn2I6O1hYusyPliHKee2tdTfNL//rc@yHtdGyP7NoEd7PWicRnQCWpGHTyonGwovrDbZkV@GnuQ3fwAh2PjrtX2Fo3NuPbJawrWDvuLgCU1wKnngQ@ByMC3180ZPMEb9@n8uRkpk@Hq@sdHB66vgi3vaAZTILzimo47q4ew3FvEORrc7MdeaPd1nn65dKlRLns6tYdhcKvnorkW9/4Aq/N1lizzrXQ0Tsf8jknWj3TnRvj3PRfMII3t1jPzKHs8AA9M7Dxku9xtYogu6rFnX@s9bF4OoLl5qnwysTuEjG7@fAjs3XlkO1SfJPjYaDavYHfkQZ58/tub87Pv2g9DCNum2OP3jehOAgfWkyD9MSaYpcduf8bwmB04tgfWV@O2h2UONScm955gPbt3i3n56M/bEFIdlstEDZfJx7KKEkUPD3KczYN4nYWNc0JID@mPVh1YOlwfplvt55oP2oQbqssUJ@GGNMCcbkPssW9sojqenYBppJl06Q1og92@Z6q4QjhoM8vW9wz1HlPzNPOhTGU5MnKdEFbviKkZXzx4eWhRu78NWKLB@hm7LYfiW2avL6jdx6X223cNNnRSTBAeMJk/EI343hyzn5xdaOFDQnPCCf49uMSPwhvK75tXoS8bufoD0Ub1mEnA/nJ9eN/5kbW@cxOINXDbHAWvN3KVOt7G7xiawhiSs4RUNeO76tlozOfaifZSO9XOybnrhcl35QGpaZLw@2ZTXoL2YtcOVAdtON/ePGwjY2xFIy12XxvCNq@vWY1ukTQnlay0CN/cOCslJYtqbQFibkxZCj1PCkgBE/uxD76ZhrFGGJws2@Wyogh8EGp5GADYHIpVzLBowYtxCQF3SxmsOyDtNineTfeNfXNGGkTcF0m3y7Gy9PloGrFS12s@tF20u42i9P69VJQ6wT4xJAZKIWvaDGqvwA1c9uB8LqdOAttndRJsz2dq8WIM@AJW4EZ20Ic9yJvAZfmOE8a8pMDrVmy/94@/97PC5JDCJH03sT0QBJbSQ5@OwskBp5tRb0WRjYVNxAGrnsczIvV5iyQTN3VGvB4Jrvrm@GI3KyZlZX14OcPNR44LrlToGgAPdsqVxrnph5RbeEZ4MWo@KYh/Yz8gE7efjhINjDpwKCtWzQsowEmMYEEah@ghFXJC@hSXY5bQfRqDbr0wvGZ5JHLyj7/zEhp0umhC2J6TZzXdHEUC9m@yupXjhGPgeo7kC43DDERGIUMUH4NEbsE/Kf@uEGdks9oeWKI6r2whGV7det46J@oRkfBEAgtdljuQi63Xf3nbNrqNb8TXYWuuY27N5Cb@rD41E7FC5iDWDO0q321A97JXImJxKmbTwuo3K/YujIp7E5GxzdQ1r1T5rHDO7I5OWKWKlSMDXKSwIg2Jc5LCq8JQc6dpFGXY0/uQI6vnKdnGYxsKIoEWL7UTPAjBqgsOKU7JVzJCW1EdYm4b8MYF4mGhz28sM6l88qq/oL0x2/LdVLVqrcGmU7xs1JusFdN@iKXg9sfOpKsnc6l0OtOfjeoUxBbGAP5ER885@u3FXVFrGl@/JvYtZNQzyWLpNbp38e7s5Ozo/KJ18eYcxDjjsywch7FvL0MEGkHkwdZyFHqstg7yiF2a/DhsLEJHJjjx/XuxyNtZDCBZoCJnTFeZWqQkH6Qqc/Xh1MGjxhAV56RB7Xcbgg1jRiQNYOc9sLPKzOItQyLLpGiTOjENoiirvQyei@sALgIiy7E/v1jIW0JtBsK5cuCMbw7Dmdw4idn/EudnrfPzH3OOUD/iHICFH1HPET5unbxcJ5yjiQBr/dnCAI/lIeTRFHaOEL8GzDKx1D23mDA7qpg7NMTrEa@f2d4yJCWLUhja0AADqgc@icbMkqYEnZKg/2uk5SUQAPt98OjebYoBASIhr34tSmBiAaauLdanChEFhE0a6yVrcPgJJArOFR9cZHAMc7Lp1KdD9X/@9W/8pKeTQvvfs/YA2v/J2x91FND60QDncSEaFMvbkzOSwCrDJ@7b09ycMNDjQuIGY0pcHyR4wwSC4JzZ5XyXeOT2W5AnKAGEiRELgxSjR@OuPErTaF/XcV0eht5AY6UUOgU9QIzTnNDXP4/x4A3iqr6zvbNlQqZO1Zs5QlbPHWJezxEqyj7Yj3DjRo2rnkPq9ToRE0gMaWPH4oLUi/bHmni1YLQIsAJfwtsExsCQ5Qjoa2bD5KJdNhUciv4nmRLpWrA6c71AgJdZA0AU/Bxk8hBhBQkzUWFpmE5TFgxv51sT2BcEIfFRTuz4dY5IBUQctyIKa7YL/EIPS97dlT2hlleD@A7BWKq/L24yHQIW8l8bLCeA9n/wdrtjqN@6m44OF7bTWj8hlO@f7@FcyOF5EGI95xh4JXJVr9Z0c0fJ@YmYoQJu0Su@AkrwA/Arh7qfwihpPT86@eX07HzthItBSvfBJCI16@WOqlXa3UVDumfzc5E@O9bPXz07ngsyz1XWdZ@rTcjvM/YAsXe8ULJOinWsETKNP4p4mcFtnMgyv8sBPuep3RpVWbmbtbv1ZicorJH/uun4uaCV8MQZWp2EHT5LZEOAWZSCLsJrMI/vnKupKUK4X/InbG42Go@vqk29T290PG8RNH3eA2ujXF/hVuFngFwGc/IQJ7IvRVMEuktajrCWp@cZmZdxFvTyI9enO19mwE@zsiW4Pv4bBx7QwLbMBU4Of6VBQG@JDFHMtyE42GNIn2OlMv8/osri5DenzX/JqqD3fftIuvNCiGBF3WIbQGsGbnzVIZ20M@gE6MvWrf6TrunWnVz0Grc6hF@lKRdHDbNcK5XLxaAkFwMMQE@e4L5xVoT4dqmJmjgFILXoKRasqhAPG8XAKtp1udhvVEtsBLxCLnkHA74lunZXtGd68QmEkwp8iSlGbSoXEwX3h4ammTPg71PoBkW94tvRnSwScYoH6Ei@6JbLyINWvEQGvumd8zIzrs65znaqVras6UPfYtFfWrXR338vmDuEiPKsfFCtPT5UVFnU9VLnxY0lte1BVfvsdM@uz87eSwVFNLdEK9gSCnrJ@PpU16@uriDOE9JWpW77sdx8@rRUsXZ2S5VDSzIrh6bxyDQVuVpVzh89eiSb5EyStmvS@Ufps1BoPgLN1nYeHz66EgpC4bJZhktrasCGULiqw8d6dzYr19taU@0220LhTih8mSFoY1p/jcDl9gs2CK7tvZdwr6vddnT28qh1flSp1tVC9cVppXr@5lnBhJftxRt21eDt9VHrxembi0qVD/nLydujN2fHreeu60ZJv5/0t053Tg/DUbd5eFjWVFU91JpdYGT6c7lZbqRpSj5clsA@XzSnb3S1Dgy8FAqvGaTaUQD2q1BoF9ryQfWganjGjTE1r83rV@Hp8vf0FDrcqfEpjI2RMTL7pmlODfrGuJ0at4Yfnpp9eFL4MXxousZgagyNwAhMcwXPw7/@afjqNARUIQxLp0aKWI0BPIenp68A2QAIf4If1zAM4G9q3MCv4Zns@nhpGIoAm@ru9k5U3fncxtIJ2d7rtunUTbsiqUidNi7xBT3pdHRuYGIVrAT7Z7PLyxeti9blpY56KxSm9WL5sKwewtVoluvZ46DQb6LUNIgIgiTLctSRLLthWyy9LuLZR9vslot39v54hgGiZJYU5tvbhmWVWll7C9pZc9eyaGI7jAlL4lzJMr2xPVk0O9PqoCoquG3bAwcza2DxBr5tKR/Nel3e2VaazZ2qEsaiNBXDWLqb8R/5blaX2aXgj6Lgx@zeVO7kOoAAjMJeOTxATd69e4d/7yY3E95iDf7t3aIz/4IX7JnJyCZSYVbAcBeQrW0FtjxU2dqRd8t72U/jsQLsiFJNwR9REuYCb5gF5F4oaNZr0axCD4jfwrQ79KjmwcaitieIcAmNHh26gVBvgn8lCYXLP7PpmNLJeDyhi@u5m@zbnz7ZEaxduqVh2K5W93a3d/dq1d3K7t7u1ra5s71dMasV8@nu0z2jYhrmrrmzu71nVna39mpbW1t70Lu991QvCYU@HWBNICIJrAjhQIok1TwQa7uQ5NaeAtuwauDBWh2PIENt1BTw@JjIRLlDC5QjxZoBGl6H2DGFwkzoY3l7a8/CQDGrN4WihEOkmlBQa@FWWCgWixBSPjfFmniqJUKDBn0UQEHEwYXka7htfgt@sQr7kVTbkmqdRoFjl82nSqFZfapBll/o8o/yFnzrFpixVc0Cmbr/V7@QVwwmOYNZNaINjeW1sKY128q1NrxPbnyIzEmS7P7UHw7d6k9XX2GTQiSpuk2IuYP6/6bW@W8dbrPyx8uPl@@rYA57ezu/A@h3NjHQu1jNBxQWurG/aTlvxe4rG7PGYLGkQ@PVGHYPC9sgaBye20PrWPnGDSb/if1zKnwTkC80CxkbEFicCktlSYkFma5C7uYFEBl7MQdXFil7TNNxHBDD4qUVROFaiyZQQVsmDQRgeTYEF9ltmBZx64gMnrDoZxTwmo8oN7Dp0UBmXLhdxRLytQjGSRNG53jJjS@XOfiMs8Xn4/h9Pm3et3gF9nysuDpyNlq5B9A2ugAjdQwpm@YfmQZsTeUFhgr509O4Nx72N8p8ToyFZWf2famKmVBKK74l4LRLkSX8KjvKHe67rG/@kyfOx6jtdy3Fb6T4LJd9ayZcyy4HKaUNv6GaVgTMWmm7XHa7DV/5VY4Y837DAGCgjZgT5W6h6aCRqStRKl/agfot6FaO20HZ7FbGldKHxpeK3TAqU/gDsVW8ymcQ3lyUctr4Ug4suw5/uAVckUTUSMq2tVoigiHXstf40ra7DUOxPBhYLh/DZIDPpO2Vy10FiHvQuT7Q8p48sctec2p5qqog1MfawXE7hUa33MD3fdmuTw@@tMcwfl@GZwPIeAowD@NWdQD4gD8LZMzVt2Sd8zhF9qbAnt9olD4clD6UGo8ff2lPVb9b4eLfN5aKR@anyHzeRuTSh7xhMZGwCqws/uzu/6yVEiJWwPpAyJUoN5JzWPoAPdHSG2b/Aw)

### Rundown

This program prints **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 6 languages have to be tested locally.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ was can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).
- Agony can be tested to output 64 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/royvanrijn/JAgony)

### Agony

Agony is another brainfuck derivative, but quite an interesting one. I found it on the list of esolangs and it seemed to be fit for this polyglot. It ignores all characters it doesn't recognise (it only recognises `$*+-@~[]()<>{}.,`). Most brainfuck programs also work in Agony, but every memory cell only has 4 bits. On top of that, the code and memory share the same space, so this language is self-modifying as well (though we don't use that here). Input and output work on two memory cells, effectively the same as brainfuck. The commands `@~{}()` are the counterparts of `+-<>[]` respectively, but they only work on one memory cell. The commands imported from brainfuck work on two memory cells.

The program stops when it reaches the first `$` and it knows two loops (`()` and `[]`) which can also be executed 0 times, effectively adding holes to the code. It's important to skip `.`s until we've placed the correct value on the tape, as that is the output command.

Let's get to the code Agony sees. As I said before, all characters it doesn't recognise are discarded. The `^` character indicates that this is either a loop that isn't executed or a comment to indicate the line number.

```
(^)-(*[^])
*[-][^line 8^]}}+<[^]>
[{}^line 12^<+++++[>++++++++++<-][^]>@@+.---@.>[^line 19^$
```

The first loop is skipped, because the memory starts as 0. Then, the memory value is decremented, so it is non-zero, so it enters the loop. Then, the `*` character is executed, which copies the current memory value and replaces it by 0. That causes the `[]` loop to not be executed. Then there's another `*`, which pastes the (non-zero) copied value. This causes the `[-]` loop to be executed, which decrements the memory value until it reaches 0. This then causes the next loop to not be executed. Then, we move the memory pointer two positions to the right, increment that memory value and then move the memory pointer back to the 0 memory value. This causes the following loop to not be executed. Then `>` moves the memory pointer to the 1 value, so the next loop is executed.

Until now, we've followed the exact same path as brainfuck, so we now reach the loop that sets brainfuck's memory cell to the ASCII value for `3`. We follow that same loop, until it reaches the output. There, brainfuck prints `41`. To print `64`, we simply add two `@` commands before the first print (they are not recognised by brainfuck, so that is not messed up), and one before the second print.

### Other changes

First of all, I added a `-` on line two, which caused several 2D languages to misalign. To fix this, I removed the tab just before it and placed it later on the same line. This fixed all the 2D languages and Whitespace was happy as well.

Secondly, I added two `}`s on line 8, which caused an Incident. `}+` was tokenised, so to counter that, I added `}+` to the very last line, just before `^_^_`.

Thirdly, I moved Cubix' code one line up, because the `o` from the Deadfish~ part caused a null byte to be prepended to Cubix' output.

I think this also is a good place to note that the `c` in the very first line turned out to be just a filler character, so we might be able to replace that in the future.

---

This is my very first contribution to this project and I couldn't have done this without the help from the people in the chatroom. I want to thank @Chance and @ais532 in particular because of their help and guidance. I'm looking forward to making another contribution soon!

Comment: "The stack"? There's no stack!

Comment: You're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

## 72. [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 1948 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1011)(22)S ␉\4n;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d@O6O4111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h> 
main (  )  {puts(p);}//*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
#s8␛dggi2␛`|$// '' 25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_X2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005219 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2030 bytes)

This program prints **72** in Fortran, **71** in what, **70** in Commercial, **69** in rk-lang, **68** in Python, **67** in C11, **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C99, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvLcttIll0bv9CbNMgyAJEACFKSJfEhybbU4@pyS2PJdkeRtAyBIAkLrwJAkbJMx2xnYha9780s@z96O1/RP1Jzbib4kEjJVREzEUOLQAJ5M/O@8r6SvrTT4a@/FujDTiP/ZuBHGcvcNGO9xLt2E4O9uGEHtpduVWuSxKGSqDdyvHDAsqHLvDAeZazv@W4qOXbGWizOZzGowQosce2eAJP6UcJoCAuufOYxJ47ZpW8PDYf5HmCPKzuAT6OAYDI3iRMX15SFrttjaew6Xt9z@FrMnWRumHpRmBrMc67Y2PN91nN9DFgg4JQxGRulS6/EcobUiySGjxPfQ3f@VHQBE7ozkt3YTjjJEYs5/TPKx4kdx0BSKrAzIJ55gZsyL1NS5tqpR3zEkNQNe5xb8ZzDEbPDZSrZtWczG/iOEj536iYZyDP4vGzoJi6mtGnxQWIHTB0nXgYWEDMP2alrJ@w8cV0Nq0AIburYMfC4syQWi2iFjAgxuLAaDeXo5FiB0MQIw44zqZDUzv/1R8lmRpMVL@r4NmW5Lh39@RW7LXaoDSwwGQQbJ6qtseY3lpqdjovvxLo0B8lUwqwSuOIzM4ozEzPbSQb0Fi39umrE/tKyrHFPEkuKJKB6kAV7HbL3ZU6XM0oSF1gsWGpfgWQ/CgfgJkhNRiFxI2TbFQjAicJeWmbuNXgWhUJC0Zjz93zoQWQpCcS@BHtshzgvNgFnJ7YBNC/n52zdNPJHHA4j04zUDzzBUJrxdZ@9Z33b82kI@mkqgXXipiM/ozGjsEdyD7zQ7RlshoYT9QgoiK6xnI1J@Qvsm2Bpt3GkAAwxRJxU6vrnX//WGwwwz6HjREkvV9b3rBc5owAI2xxZG4pI6hqFts/RAlyZVhfDscC17Xs9O6Plw5t8CY4EX3Ucjfwei7BgMvawsYb2NTZjv@86mStUPBplwLHMAvtK2AhP6C0ID@xLCJYvwNfmZOvs4CWk5LhCYfRglPV3mB4fMSU1P6r7e@r@044L3DRD2yia5qAObTM2@Cs8KY8pzvvDhTxJe869iHaRHw9HsBnoCdMY1iQhZjo2yEnJqGSwe2V2yRnNLREUnW/RsaskLrvEvp4RxnVE6ACN12nf5jMsZDqDu6tibm9Jw6CdULIsXTESfjTGwhw3Mp7Q6ZAWtwc2lspygg4FQWJF/uYuaVchNJ1mu3TZjn7pQTqkBzA1uTCWaAR4rSpgMJuQ3tKmCOwbzOIIE72QJPP6EHIAvU1umOPSZsCucIWdo0VGXDFSD3oU9VlFr25tfUf4WWIe6j@btv7FfFTGRPw9MR@yvjtmvh0ORvYAihyFGGI7jhtn@Q4CJWmGPXLfDPKXem7TjXQoFQ/ur81tW27tl9Yg6yOkl1tom9QejArAat3HLmd2MuA7kfW8BPvFv7m/OgCu7y0ufyKQOwh8kh9AYeaYoGTuxHVGGbYbFHk89JwhdJewC8WGFdbx/vJ4tbw6TI7eny9NyFitZ1XJMOevCI0Hp9BJoqvzwOrTVK07L7jwl188PrOdBmsmjuYowkItvTVM24Du5UyDNz@jSALmb@a6@c6ahxdzfoLBP5JjStxfRhAY9NkbhARih3O3v2QZvTRU4Cq81APXyYGTrp@/PiF/8MEVMQz4LnzZsjGPENFgeO6gqWMmBMl1hhHTQ6bkOKgy96efgZaZJg5v6EtBhKwZ4JNK/OJds4k@i9jsvkNlrVU4vqRSZm1Z7pbhw/wUKhSOfB8Po5BvMdXVbqFrjpumBjYMeGtQNALs5JKrTe8CZsMkGjN3qtWVdcv9ToG8HF16k/@HEnEIL3EFVUti4K9@ixxWAGeCkOWcdSsQnHcvo4DsPPvAKSZ8XyTwDX34Aym@yYawdLrDZLsZxS5QumNJFOCJ4FzV6jygUxTjc@SF6q3y9OlTZU9pKWW09tFqUGufWiW09nlL5y2CM6jFR5R5i3rbfAS96yrT9mzmidYl0U4oav3ixard3turdct228rvVbprcCbwHYDW6YZ5FK3ZpKamya0xCDUu@5Ig/xzC@QkhH/vJI0/cR4C4SByk@WIdSRbMqN21pfKipypi1fdmAPYZ8c36KEJenooPeOOFVxHpqBnMWhcVw9q6MwXyndWRfS8d8ssd0BW0Vnv46DS47PPLGoC9PAxATEE5EvGFmzKKRKIImj/mYEEURgIV8MsLbfMtvxnwHuvwuWuk7yDzwsWeH7j6bs289ELz0u0/BHn84sVrDtO/vPQeAgJTCO/ZfQ1YMrpcxzPEZsMVJ87ucP18lGS@3jMzurv//W89cH9VNkP7JkU0fzVvXIBpJCe9/6Co8qH0wC/rxfp55CPT@84cjk0RvO3PG@vn2mNvXeg@xBryBA@Y@j7sCVgGO7eq3NgX/qjnzu7rJ@U8vBsLiNGhF@jQ7G2jwgWIR4pvuPV5YJZ7AY2YhhKfxI/snilSUc9dSFTw3p3Ygyi8MZc8m5Fc/gZUZzEHW@Se2XCUjcSVEs7vyc6L6fvYhswhK1uHL6yj/PYAPJDYfkh3xbYhU60f@/aVeUnNiz6a60kVxCTeANnt7P4Q2Iez2HZcc5zSba3avEGk6NsJO/vzu7PTR/WHT4gQMvHFde10r0MHvjXMvj8TqPT55fcoHtcDx/ahfTWhe1Ty0ZfY5N1jrG9f3pBLG/5@HaJVB6US06NFIraoKMXxw4Mch@mwPU1nd3f9aFF84hM4EXJm93vOCB7FC0B3tbfUfFA5vEhf5H2p0CiKA9YZIfvaRlzg2yl0JMvZ7F5DLPzymM6Sq3BIeRatxzT2HlKz3Puh9G0xMvacCE495vKmBx8Pa5YJKd67HxstpqHCIr8shtJTrrivEP6QB/72qOZGTkZZ0wO68xvMkkhYKCVc0gsjeohpTjSm74Oefxhdu@K63h19WYvVbzA7us9VAkH36vCe8z1t/eClMDq4rDeHV2uxyhx/7XuyUVGCjDVlVaPyqHjWKvOZ8dr4yTgxztiZ50fpo/xAvp6m4rpelRegl4lnh7pDOrzcXj9sLWLctbFDfn1AwLY/iPztnYFp47KWN2ejpE@2/TG2PG6jLOu7NmoezUShld8fwji5wt9aTJGfBDDelN591zk8bMHyoP9huhDp08j1NB1XdmgkTxje8qrwvEyTlvNiNt55SV68TOfnAwV4tsTlRZtZGsoKVEoaBTB8WZQYjMOpql0qaZokBtEWGoQAm0HxGi2VyUT5N2WwZRmHRarTbrPi7WSvsmdNWZPJezLrdsWsvGBzNIl5cfWtGNou2t1mUdF1pah0wj1WUTioizx9Pah9B67v8ZvAc0E6C@2AV@aoPaO0Lsp/MDRU8x3aYQ@R3rvQ4xm2EyWiiCUqpTyq/sffe3kpfOCCyMBLbR@MoMObKHCH0XhfrJuvfhjHNpXSaQ7EFr7IwfWXhywde5kzFBVw2MF3x@c7efkyP0zCwymFeEtYCKGiC8ljZmdCaAKbXuQK1csXno@aEQXnMgpCNvZ62TA1YDFCx@Xl0VnJDpgkBBZmSUSqW2avWc@loIeXED6PIFs/iq545YIw@cffRdEWnR6pELVny/NThKUVGYyLxSuljhONgPVski9uEuUgKjEZLnIEjtxg47jivcacoc2rydBEfVZLpWVEPfXl4RnTj5hCZ2BUWq17fbV4@PaP79uVbvMbC0wkQCZVczjf5B/051Yql9kMpD4lvVrurqB70aswuTiRc7LovIUfL8yVSuwmplKbi2tWGw34UQ3XO3fMa6O8AB5SBEBnIGGK/YFHjU8tNk2zqCJzCryM6WcZ26KDQhcsQUsc7jA6eqM6Hw0pTthXNiRd0R1mbVXwJBjiU2k5aC7y1eWCgfnKvRzxwPq6alRrTU5O8aLZaPFW4vYiOnxof@yMu2Y640qnM/mhUp2AbVEC8Gcm7ZyjP7@6LRqtytevqX3DZHmq1HlBh7Z38fb09enR2fnh@bszsHEqqCwcR0lgL0wEKUHsw8gPI5@f5oAfieem3zcbT7jdkJ7kgKrKijZrMKvCYKGezA1LzlZZl4uiKfq4JZn33evMzUffY7mpY6dc2rlglXTZzJVnCkDMw54cwa7OkIfi3K4xV5wcmTVBkA6COPgc4fnTOsLu9nJ4wfB9egbTczKWoTipC6j1QESrAM7xFjACybVETP@XMI/hR76POUF9D3MAS99bfWnh48PXP60uvLQmAaz0z3Vj6eD8aAKvDAvY57pNxzMzjYny47WZSYDFH4qaLyKFuVFL5@Vb0qE@mWQfu5q2A09uU9rWjCyIwQ79FCa014NNuLzJyKTAloqK7bxsKxdAujH3cGUmSwSbNlePWWAyxgiWnE9icJHD8ZnTdSeVHdf851//Jk4nOxna/563@2j/p2h/NIlBq8dZAsc5a4gt71@fshR@ShAe2JMlmshVkCvywhEiwAAcvOYMIXCB7ILexTxq@z34CSGAmWTzyMzx9dykqw6zLN4zTfLsCD37Bi95uRPIAVbScKLA/GVEh8WwzOb21vamZQJJ/Xo2IT@DGFD9RUyoaXvQH@nai5ufLh3WaDSYnCKBd5vbdcFIs2h/rMmf5ogWASuJIKDNMAZDFiPQ18qHqUW7ZGk0lPafYimsW4d/F3KBi1B5AyAavQ5zfsjwQVHOKjrOcCcZN6c3s@AGkUUYsYD4xH8yMJtIx0Ribk2WVnQX@KKHF1m8O1GlsSwG@QOB8ZLMnrxOdRg05L/WaE6I9n@IdrtT0b911x13z3XncPVUW71/Jk20sIOzMKK62zFwZWrVrNZMa1tb2idyPhWwpV3xFVNiH2BfOa73OYrTw5dHr388OT1bOZXlkMp9MIUprUapoxvldnfeUO7p/IylL47NszcvjmeMXMYq77qP1brJ7yP2wGIfREFrdSnesbKQVfmtEy8S7LWELNLvJcCXIvNeWVXVbqftbqPVCQsry39d95OJgrFBv5JAq5PyH0wobI2BmZfszqMrqMcjZ8F6RhDel@VTYS8fTUeu1ZbZc69NOiOUDHPWA9@oNu5gq4lza8GD2fKwE/mboiVj3cVajrRSRllGRKSy0RyTOyPnzCaaT0ROx3/2YYcI5xPPEdApN64i8@O/UUDs/zpbpAtIQbChPJ4V3fAMANt8XpboebxiZSc3OQXznjM38PTzGT606RcHcTBCSFWReKRD37us2832hM2PqR47ozPS2PcylQ7HJgZlVqBG1YgAq@G7dLbW2O3mB3lsdt5W4kd2pyPw6zSK2SKbfeXOWm@R0LBXI0wODXDZj6MAcH1@e@uShXfZnyMdg8FHZYZEG6uoOQ1G0NvC6sbQnfS8AbyEqpVhUH6wrMVhn62VkIUqsKGCVX@kWssyY37XAeUSx@y2bXhhz52oyljR9rrEHbxXxh@uFU1e0QF@SpofmfbuH5fO9r6d5ZtwftS4vHFmAQsWzw8q4EToR2x0PI0UwYNOH/zJDUOojAq0AygIs0egM9HKs19Slue/e1myC/@Sn3vc9xJHyq0fwRcWzTpPRupTOIRPHdbJOv1OSF6hfmP@wTTM@q1a9Js3Jhy51lKLw6ZVqm2USsVwQy2G5MqePaMcZlqEp7wwZEOeAEgv@lod/IRnbRbDetFuqMVes7rBR@CxVNJuMeBbahq3RXtqFp/BMZXxJhHaoRZTjcRRMQxrCvxIQkWzHNjxrSozeUI/H6Lli16pRDgYxQtC4JvZOStxM9U5M3nWVM8DJHMQzNT4jjL8@mvB2kaUPlWj0n619vRAZ7K50Xl1XVfadr9q/NI9vTo9/YvWUZXCyxPZ2pTrG6ZUMDcqX5@b5qdPnxAzMK2tK9222nr@fKNc397ZKB/UFat8YFUsS1OrVe2MPelshvUnT56o1qmibNWUs4904L3/FP/4Hz7zR7o@5W/y1xxk9fNUY@ovE6nQegIlqW0/PXjySSpIhYtWCR@DX0ulvb0DXdcn@BqlfanwqQGYRnc6LTXaDaPV0ruttlS4lQqTqVSoykT6hlRoThpv@ej2q3ya0i8/4dLQu@349Kejw7OjcrWhF6rHhy/L1bN3LwoWnrYWj9RZo8e3R4evTt6dl6ti1B9fvz96d4r3nufFaa@X9qJht3VwUDKA4IHR6gKZyQ@lVqmZZRn7@WLDsBOp8Ko1eWfqDSDwk1R4y2H1jgbor1KhXWir@9X9asWvXFesK@vqTXSy@Ds5wXtvUvkcJZVhZWj1Dk62TzYty5pU3HeVm8rNpBJEJ1YPTRf/KgGaXqU/qQwqYSW0rDuTPfwXnERvTiJMFWFYNqlkNGulj/vg5OQNJutj9c/451UqhOSkco2/im/xz8eLilaRkAR2t7bj6vYvbW5Utna7bXfiZV2ZlZVOW@nWC2ba6ZhCi@UqFJG6p9OLi1eH54cXFyblRpNGsXRQ0g/wabZKjfy2X@i1iG2GpKjI0@KOAhdh13ktqUjHqW2rWyre2nujKVkgtmFtaNx6bFXq9Y3DvL2Jdt7cqdfd1HY4BnVFoKSqLtydKludSbXPqjL3IrvYw1at0VC3t7RWa3sLj9s7mq5WqHNT@2jNu6palMjKRI4Shd1OxT/1dtpQ@Uejf5pGL/NrS7tVGwABzJbGn8UAgI0/fPhA3w/j67Fo8YZ492HeufzAG/hcPzB2tYH8EP6WKYVpgQxyyDa3NIT3rra5re6UdvN/zacasJdrSg3Yy4o0E1bTKhCxUsGov5WtKnogvDrVqCLfNXzE0LVdScZHal66Ay@UGq1bCe7mEiHEmD2vIJzw6ag16vefSrYnuuA6kXMg4U5d36fkjSLHcZT4vTGiGYJDHp0wm35Zj22Vpi4@wantjlx3PBqN3fnnpZfu2Z8/2zHZOni/imSQp6pWd3e2dnZr1Z3yzu7O5pa1vbVVtqpl6/nO891KGfZux9re2dq1yjubu7XNzc1d9G7tPpcKbtjz@qYJ22LByNC95/apRDfaYXJtp1OR529iliLAifpKrOjW/mhH3n4u78m154BAWEa/MGjQbzEiY9hiEv2shqmwwIzd0rZRY60@xfwztBcL0zvhAFT5ObRTqaOrfh@MJVd7SFMTipU5NELJ7V2ZXgNETMC2LakwlXp0cri5WyfzOW20pKJCyCg1qaDXos2oUCwWYWrPW3JNPjGkJg2HPAsyjS2kX6Mt61v4Y72wFyu1TaXWaRbELrKea4VW9bmR2jeFrnjH1E287Bb43qtaBTbx/q/@opT1x/wz3xkr@2SpteZ5fB2AvJ0/9AYDr/qHT1@RKzBFYdUtxqxt5BDmN70h/hq4vDwRVMvbW7IGjUzTjxcfL/5Shabt7m4XfsXgR7IL9M6Do76LuGEUrIuODhPvjU3lnHAeIaHxZoQweq5TjJSK4s5h6@47rmh3XvH/6YB3EuFFMlepATPqlHmNiW1wk9rV2O2sMqlSLxXHtHktLXGzURKySl3UPGkKrz5vYhXaBaxJALwABsupek2rzrwGTYY7Yqh8BfrMRpSa1KTYnWPhdbW6tFwk5Ji0MHoJl6XxpZIAnwq0BD1O0BNki775I9AL6DDFUfPR2j2AdqULGKVTUXIyfwsZCJLV@Qxl9rvJuDce4aI2o4mjsOjM3y9EMZU2snJQl4jsjbgu/Ul1tFsKY@vfgmfPnI9xO@jWtaCZ0b1UCupT6Ur1BMhG1gyaulWPgWw9a5dKXrcZaH9SY4580KwAGGvTzKl2O5d02MzFlWrlL@1Q/xZ2y8ftsGR1y6Pyxs/NL2W7WSlP8AXbyn75FzBvxko1a34phXW7gS9F1Hc4ETfTkl2/W7vFkCvVb35p291mRav7GFgqHYMY4Jm2/VKpq2FxH52rA@v@s2d2yW9N6r6uawT1sbZ/3M7Q6Jaa9Lyn2o3J/pf2COP3VNybWMbXgDzG3ZUB5gN@dfBYiG@BusBxQuhNgF7QbG78vL/x80bz6dMv7YkedMuC/XuVheAJ@Qkhv6wj6sbPy4rFWcIPV1T5B2/vB2MjZXIZ2gcml@OlkQLDjZ/REy92w/R/AA)

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident tested to output 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ and Moorhens were [tested by WheatWizard.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37922205#37922205)
- Surface can be tested to output 66 [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).
- Japt was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).

## Explanation

### Fortran

Fortran is another old and famous language we're able to add to the polyglot. It’s original spec appeared in 1956 which is a just prior to ALGOL 58, which I believe makes this the oldest high-level language we’ve added. Assembly is, I believe, the oldest overall.

Of course we’re not using the original compiler, because that wouldn’t work. We’re using GCC’s Gfortran interpreter and we're using the 08 version of Fortran, although the Fortran code we’re using is compatible with other versions, it’s just the one I arbitrarily picked.

The biggest problem with adding Fortran was that the language doesn’t have a block comment, which is the #1 trick for hiding the polyglot. But, Gfortran happened to have C style preprocessor directives if you’re file extension is among the following (.fpp, .FPP, .F, .FOR, .FTN, .F90, .F95, .F03 or .F08), which is the track I took. I happen to be using F08.

I had originally planned to hide the polyglot in a non-executing preprocessor if block, but the lines contained therein continued to be read by the pre-processor unfavorably. But I stumbled into the realization that C-style comments appearing within pre-processor directives are treated as comments. After some experimentation I found that `#endif//*` entered a comment block for Fortran, but not the C family, nor asm. This appears to be because the GFortran supports C style block comments, but not line comments. Our asm interpreter naturally treats lines starting with a `#` (that it doesn’t recognize as a preprocessor directive) as a comment.

Once C comments were handled, I just needed to put in the following line in a space only read by Fortran `print'("72")';end;` and we made a successful polyglot.

### /* Comments */

The comments were the main difficulty with this addition, so I’m going to step through the comment state of all the languages that use `/*` comments since I changed them so drastically. C11, C99 and C++ all use the same comment path, unsurprisingly, so I’ll just refer to this group as C. The other unique comment blocks are in asm and Fortran.

The polyglot starts out with a preprocesser directive of the form of `#1 ""`, which refers to a line number and file name in quotes. The previous answers followed this with a `//*` to line comment in C and block comment in asm. Fortran didn’t accept this comment style, so things had to change, and the fix was to change line 1’s comment to a block style comment with a `#1 ""/* bla */` pattern.

Line 2’s answer held Japt, which it somewhat syntactically rigid in the polyglot, so I opted to leave Japt’s line 2 answer intact. Japt transpiles to JavaScript BTW, which is another `/*` style comment language, but these comment indicators can get altered in the transpolation. The `/*` at the beginning of line 2 is such a case. By converting the `//` comment to a `/*` comment on line 1, japt needed the `/*` comment to close, so a `*/` was added to the end of line 1.

This BTW broke <><, so we now redirect it’s IP to line 2 since `/` is conveniently a reflector.

Okay, so line 1 is a single line block comment for C, a `#` style line comment for asm, and an unknown preprocessor directive for Fortran, which only issues a warning. Line 2 starts a block comment for C and Fortran, and asm again ignores it as a line comment. The Fortran block comment is in the middle of a preprocessor directive and so is required to end the comment just prior to the completion of the directive, or with a line feed. I chose the latter.

From here, asm continues to see line comments until we arrive at `#2""/*\*` which is the pre-processor pattern from before. The `\*` exists here because Agony needed a second `*` to complete its copy paste operation, and Retina needed the `\` to escape out the second `*`.

Ok, we’ve established the 3 languages in a comment and can move down the polyglot to evil’s line where we drop out of the comment and begin the real work.

We start with a `#if 0` directive, valid in both C and Fortran as initiating a non-executing preprocessor if block. Perfect! We can answer asm within the block and move to close the block as well as start a Fortran comment with `#endif//*`.

Following this, we have to close asm so we’ll once again use our preprocessor output file syntax to begin an asm comment, which leaves only C open. So we’ll just answer for the C family and end with `//*/` , which sets asm and Fortran comments to a closed state.

Now, all the comments are closed, and we need to have a state when only Fortran is open. I don’t actually see a good way to do this, so I take the verbose track of starting a Fortran only comment with `#endif//*` and then toggling all 3 languages with `/*/`.

Finally! We can answer Fortran with `print'("72")';end;` and then put Fortran back into a comment with the same if block trick from before. Hurray!

Currently we’re closing the comment for all 3 on the final line with `*///` which somehow works for all 3 and I don’t totally understand why. But I accept that it is valid and that is enough.

### What

I massively busted What with my changes, and it turns out that any change has a 2/3 chance of busting what, if the code is placed prior to its code. So I move it into line 2, to mitigate that problem going forward.

This caused some Cubix problems because the starting IP was dead center in INTERCAL. I fixed by changing some INTERCAL `DO`s to `FAC`s and adding a padding `x` at the end of line 2.

### Golf Report

I cut `!` on line 2 after finding experimentally that it was not needed by Underload.

Similarly, I removed  `)` and a `(` near the beginning of line 1 because Underload could get by without it.

Prelude no longer needed the space in the Brain-Flak’s code, so I cut that.

Alphuck got its end of polyglot `s`’s rearranged because the changes to line 1 caused the 2D langs that wrap around the polyglot to be off by 1 column. I had to shorten the last 2 lines to match so, I moved some leading `s`’s to near the end.

There is a bit of overhead to put code at the end of the polyglot, so rk was ripe for some byte saving simply by moving it. Now it lives near the beginning of the final C family comment block.

### Incident Report

`<>{nd` became `<>{` because `nd` was no longer needed to be detokenized
Removed the space between }} and `+` in `#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[` to detokenize because `}}+` no longer needed to be detokenized.

I removed `“6”` at the end of commercial with no good reason.

Added a `5` to the Brain-Flak line.

removed the `59` detokenizing string from the Minimal-2D space and replaced it with a `q` to detokenize `q` because e the space was now only 1 char wide. Never replaced the 59

Comment: Hey, that `"6"` was added to detokenize a `"6`, I had a good reason for it, I swear :P

Comment: "clock comments"

Answer (score 12):

## 77. C++14, 2089 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111\4O6O@x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;'␉;print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}() )wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉p(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0_"
main (  ){puts( sizeof( 0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":p(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":"77" );"7";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@<>
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"# xi xi xi xi \++++>/ xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004575 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2171 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLd9tKcl4bJ/9gNm2Q1wBE4kWKevEhybY08R17pFiynWOSliEQFGHhwQuAImWZPtkmJ4vZzybL@R@zza@YP3LzVTf4kETJ955kEVoEGujqrmdXVVfT5046@PXXAn3YcRxcXwRxxjIvzVgv8a@8xGDPr9me46e1SlWSOFQS90auH12wbOAxPxqOMtb3Ay@VXCdjLTbMZzGowQos8ZyeAJP6ccJoCAsvA@Yzdzhk54EzMFwW@IA9tLYAn8YhwWReMkw8XFMWeV6PpUPP9fu@y3Exb5J5UerHUWow371kYz8IWM8LMGBBgFvGZGyULr0S6AypF0sMH3d4h9z5U9EDTOTNWPaGTsJZjtmQ8z/jfJw4wyGIlArsBIRnfuilzM@UlHlO6pMcMST1oh6X1nAu4Zg50TKX7Mp3mAN6RwmfO/WSDOwZfF428BIPUzqE/CJxQqaOEz@DCEiY@@zYcxJ2mnieBixQgpe6zhB03EIJZDFhyIgRgyur0VAOjg4VKE2MMJxhJhWS6um//Cw5zGiy4lkd36Ys16WDP79kN8UOtUEFJoNih4nqaKz5naVmp@PhO7HPzYtkKmFWCVIJmBkPMxMzO0kG8hYt/apiDIMltKxxRxNLhiSgetAFexWx92XOlztKEg9ULETqXILlII4uIE2wmowikkbENiwowI2jXlpm3hVkFkdCQ/GYy/d04ENlKSnEOYd4HJckLxYBFyeWASwvl@cMbxoHIw6HkWlG5geZYCjN@KrP3rO@4wc0BP00laA68dJRkNGYUdQjvYd@5PUMNiPDjXsEFMZXQOdgUv4C6yZcWm2cKABDDTFnlbr@8Ze/9i4uMM@@68ZJLzfW96wXu6MQBDucWAeGSOYaR07AyQJcmbCL4UBw5QR@z8kIfXSdo@BEcKzjeBT0WAyEydjHwho4V1iM/b7nZp4w8XiUgcYyC51L4SN8YbdgPHTOoViOgOPmbOts7wW05HrCYPRwlPW3mD48YEpqflJ3d9Tdpx0PtGmGtlY0zYs6rM1Y46/wpDxmOO/3F/ok6zn1Y1pFwXAwgs9AT5QO4U0SEqbrgJ2UnEoGv1dm51zQ3BPB0PkSHXtK4rFzrOsZY9xGhA3QeJ3WbT7DQqczuNsm5vWWLAzWCSPL0ntOIojHQMxpI@cJm44IuXPhAFWWM7QvGBIY@ZvbrF1GsHSa7dxjW/q5D@2QHcDV5MpY4hHg1YqAwWxCe0uLInSuMYsrXPRCk8zvQ8kh7Da5Zq5HiwGrwhN@jpCMuGGkPuwo7jNLr9RqP1B@lpj7@kfT0b@aj@qYmL@j5n3W98YscKKLkXMBQ44jDHFc1xtm@QoCJ2mGNXLXDfKXeu7TjXQgFffu4ua@Lff2SzjI@wjt5R7aIbOHoEKIWg@wypmTXPCVyHp@gvUSXN/FDoCrO8jlzwRyi4DP8gMkzAITjMybeO4ow3KDIY8HvjuA7RJ1kViwwjveRY9Xy9jhcvT@HDURY7eeVSTDnL8iMh6cQieN3p8HXp@mat16wZW//OLxmZ00XDFxPCcRHmrprWE6BmwvFxqi@QllEnB/s9DNV9Y8vZjLEwL@mQJT4v0ygsJgz/5FRCBONA/7S57RTyMFocJPfUidAjjZ@umrI4oHHzyRw0DuIpYtO/MYGQ2G5wGaOmZKkDx3EDM9YkpOgyrzePoFZJlp4vKGvpREyJoBOakkL941m@iLyM3uBlTWug/HUSpl1pblbhkxLEhhQtEoCPAwivgSUz3tBrbmemlqYMFAtgZlI6BOLnna9DZgNkjiMfOmWl1Zhe53KuTF6Nyf/D/UiEt0iSu4WlIDf/Vb9HAPcKYIWc5Fdw@Cy@5FHJKfZx84x0Tv8wSxoY94IA2vswE8ne4y2WnGQw8k3fIkCuhEcq5qdZ7QKYrxJfYj9UZ5@vSpsqO0lDJau2g1qLVLrRJau7yl8xbBGdTiI8q8Rb1tPoLedZVpezbzROuSaieUtX71h6rT3tmpdstO287vFbprCCaIHYDW6YZ5FK3ZpKamya0xGDXO@5Jg/xTKeY2Uj732KRL3kSAuNg7SHFlHkoUwqrd9qbzoqYhc9b0ZQnzG8Hp1FiEvT8UHvPGjy5hs1AxnrTPLsGu3psB@5/7Ivp8O@OUW6D2y7vfw0Wl43ueXFQA7eRqAnIL2SCQX7sooE4ljWP6Yg4VxFAtSIC8/csy3/GYgeqyi57aTvkXMcw9r/sLTt6vmuR@Z517/IcjD589fcZj@@bn/EBCEQnTP7ivAktH5KpkhNxvcC@LsltRPR0kW6D0zo7v33//Wg/Tv62bgXKfI5i/njTMIjfSk9x9UVT6UHvhltVq/jALs9H4wh@tQBu8E88bquXbYWw@2D7VGfIMHSoMA/gQig5@7b9xYF8Go583uqyflMrydC4jRkR/qsOwNw@IKxCPlN9z7PDDLnYRGTEMbnySInZ4ptqK@t9CokL03cS7i6NpcimxGcv4bSJ3lHGyx98wGo2wkrrTh/JHu/CF9H1uQOaRV239uH@S3B@BBxMZDtiuWDblq/TBwLs1zap710VzNqmAm8S@wu53dHwL7cDJ0XM8cp3R70H9Eo3TIFclbD4Ehe0wCcX0IxI9cRNZo0XgIECwG/PJ7rI4bgesEML2qMDyq9@hLMvLvSDVwzq8png1@vwER1otSienwIU23VLKqTI8XG7JFZWk4fHi86@bjt7dXjxZFKD6BG2Pv7P0oKCGy@CFEUOktNR80Ej/WF/u/VFgW5QOrnJFz5SA/CJwUtpLlEveuoCF@ecx2KWS4o8BJFq3HLPcOUbM9@EPbuMXIoe/GCO7CVOkh8Fdaa0R5390caTENFRj5ZTGUnnI3@hJpEEXi74/60tjNaPf0gBn9BvckNi60NVyyCyN@SGhuPKbvgyt4EF954ro6LH1dSdVvcD96wE0Cyff94T33R9b6wU/hfHBZ7RYvV1KVucHK9zvsTRwn2LmmrGJYj6pnpTGfGK@M18aRccJO/CBOH5UH9u1pKq6rTXkBep74TqS7ZMPL7dXDVhLGQxzb59cHFOwEF3GwsXVhOrg8aAWjpE/ePr//Vic3d1K2/UMnNU9r4sjO7w@6@Ev8/chAqCoCn@5TfjNvrjaWH3i0fDPwMJvYAdDI1SweWltzG0tSb6VxAXcOs5@4g7Fz/agJ/iiePCTsWTzZoSo@T6UfJeaHaNYfRcN3Tm95eXxer0rLeVUf7/wkr@Km84OSwqvITTxevZrtx1mBamqjEJ4/ixODcThVdUolTZPEIPIhFxHAZlC8WE31QlEHTxmcecZhsedrt1nxZrJj7dhT1mTyjsy6XTErr1wdTIa8yvxWDG0XnW6zqOi6UlQ60Q6zFA7qBVDkSlDnFlzf5zdB54J1FjkhL1FSe8ZpXdRB4Wmp@D1woh5S3neRz0sNbpyIap4oGfPtxd//1svPBC48MBn6qRNAEHSKFYfeIB7vCrw59v3h0KEzBZoDmVYgihH6i32Wjv3MHYijAASCd4enW3kdNz9Vw8Mx5bpLVAilogu76MzJhNIENb3YE1aVI56PmjGF6DoKIzb2e9kgNeAyI9fjdeJZ7RKUJAQWZUlMVllmr1jPo7SP11K@jKDbII4veQmHKPn730T1Gp0@mRC1Z@j5ccoSRgbvavOSsevGI1A9m@Srl8Q5iEpCRo4wgkSusSY88V5j7sDhZXVYoj4rKhMaUVh@sX/C9AOm0GEg1Zjrfl8t7r/94/u21W1@Z6GJnaBJZS0uN/knfdNO5TKbgdSnZFfL3Ra6F70Kk4sTOWeLDp74OcvcqMRqYiq1ubpmReKQn1lxu/PGvEjMTwIiSoHoMChKsT7wqPGpxaJpFlVsIUM/Y/pJxmp0YupBJGiJUy5GZ5BU8KQhxQn7xgZkK7rL7JqFJyGQgGrsYXOxcV@unJgvvfMR32FcVYxKtcnZKZ41Gy3eSrxeTKcw7U@dcddMZ1LpdCY/WZUJxBYnAH9m0so5@PPLm6LRsr59S@E7ZXmq1Hlli5Z38eb41fHByen@6bsTiHEquCwcxknoLFwEGcEwQGgbxAE/1oI8Et9Lf@w2nnC/IT3JAVWVFR3WYLbF4KGezB1LLlZZl4uiKfq4J5n33enM3UffZ7mrY8dc27lilXTZzZVnBkDCw5ocwa/OiIfh3KxwV5wdmTXBkA6GOPic4PnTKsZu93J4IfBdeobQczaWoTirC6jVQMSrAM7pFjCCyJVMTP@PKB8ijvyYcoL6EeUAln6EfQnx4f6r1@/eHtzHvYQ2h7kHMreQpd8RHEyQjMAP9rmF02nVzG7i/LRx5hjg9weiBO4EC9eWzqvZZEl9cswB1jYtCr7XT2lxM/IjBtsPUjjSXg@e4fw6I8cCjyoK2PMqtlyAAIx5nCszWSLYtHn/1AmOY4yU0f0sBhc5HJ85XXVw2/HMf/zlr@KwtpOh/e95u4/2f4r2J5MEdP90T9A4Fw2J5f2rY5YiWgnGQ2eyxBMFDApIfjRC1hRCgldcIAQuiF3wu5hHbb@HPKEECJM8Hzk7js9Luuogy4Y7pknxHRl43@AVQG8CPcBXGshZzV9GdHYO/2xu1DbWbRNE6lezCfmRzAWVo8SEmrYDE5Ku/GHz87nLGo0Gk1PXCbzmRl0I0iw6n6ry5zmhRcBKIhVoM4zBkMUI9LXyYWrRKdkaDaVVqNgK69YR5YVeEChU3gCIRq@jXB4yIlGci4pOd7xJxp3q9SzFQX4RxSwkOfFfUMwm0jGRmFuTpXu2C3rRw2tO/q3c0lhWg/yBwHiFakdeZToMFvJfKywnQvs/RLvdsfTv3VWn/3Pb2b9/yK/ePaInXtjeSRRTGfIQtDK1Ylaqpr2hLa0TOZ8K1NKq@IYpsQ6wrlzP/xIP0/0XB69@Pjo@uXdIzSGVu2AKU1qNUkc3yu3uvKHcsfmZSJ8fmidvnh/OBLlMVd51l6pVk98l7AFkH0SR7z4q3nEPkW391okXdYaVjCyqEEuAL0QB4h5WVbuZtruNVicq3EP/bdUvSArGGv1oBK1Oyn8/orAVDubVrHR5Gl/CPB45GtczgvC/Lh@SzwqfdAJdaZk978qkI1PJWJRE5aLauEWtJo7xhQxm6OEn8jdFWwbeBS5XuldNWiZEbOjjOSW3Rs6FTTwfiZ0d/xWMEyGpT3xXQKfcuYr9H//JBnYAr7LFpgEbESwon@@Nrvk@AMt8Xp3p@bxw5yTXOQfznhMv9PXTGT206BfnknBC2KFj@5EOAv@87jTbEzY/tXvsyNJIh4GfqXRWODFofwVuVI0YsBuBR0eNje1ufq7JZsePJX6CeTyCvI7jIVvsaV96s9ZbbGvYyxEmhwV47OdRCLg@v731yMN77M@xjsGQozIjog0sas6DEfZqwG4MvEnPv0CUULUyHMpPtr04@3S0EvaiCnyoENUfqeS0LJjfdV67JDGn7Rh@1PMmqjJWtJ0uSQfvlfGHK0WT79kAPzTOT5B7d0@PZ2vfyfJFOD95XV44s4QFyPNzGwQR@k0fndZjo@DDpvf@5EURTEYF2SEMhDkj8Jlo5dkPS8vznwEt@YV/zo@B7kaJA@UmiBELi2adb0nqUwSEzx3WyTr9TkRRoX5t/sE0zPqNWgya1yYCudZSi4OmXaqulUrFaE0tRhTKnj2jncy0iEh5ZsiGPAGQXgy0OuSJyNosRvWi01CLvWZljY/AY6mk3WDA99Q0borO1Cw@Q2Aq400irEMtphqpwzIMewr6SENFsxw6wxtVZvKEfk1F6It@qUQ0GMUzIuC72TkpcTfVOTH53qmeJ0jmRTgz41vG8OuvBXsDufpUjUu7lerTPZ3J5lrn5VVdaTv9ivFL9/jy@PhftY6qFF4cyfa6XF8zpYK5Zn3bNM3Pnz8jZ2BaW1e6bbW1ublWL29srZX3yrZSrhdYYFu2ramVitZZj07Yk/qTJ09U@1hRalXl5BP9BGD3Kf7xP3zmj3R9yt/krznI/c9Tjam/TKRC6wnspLrxdO/JZ6kgFc5aJXwMfi2Vdnb2dF2f4GuUdqXC5wZgGt3ptNRoNxpGqzVp6d1WWyrcSIXJVCpUZBLAmlRoThpv@QTtl/lMpV9e49LQu@3h8euD/ZODcqWhFyqH@y/KlZN3zws2nmqLR@qs0uPbg/2XR@9OyxUx6o@v3h@8O8Z73/eHaa@X9uJBt7W3VzJA457R6oKYyU@lVqmZZRn7eLZmOIlUeNmavDP1Bgh4LRXecli9owH6m1RoF9rqbmW3YgXWlWVf2pdv4qPF39ER3vsT60ucWANrYPds2@6sH20c7U0s7511bV1PrDA@sntoevhnhWj6Vn9iXViRFdn2rdke/guP4jdHMaaKMSybWBnNavVxvzg6eoPJ@kD/Bf98yyIqJ9YV/qzA5p9PZ5ZmSdgRdmsbw8rGL23uW2rb3bY38bOuzMpKp6106wUz7XRMYcxyBfZI3dPp2dnL/dP9szOTtkiTRrG0V9L38Gm2So38tlvotUhuRkNSVOzahh0FocKp88pSkU6Z23a3VLxxdkZT8kRszV7TuBepWfX62n7eXkc7b27V617quJyEuvJEEKWqHuKeKtudSaXPKjIPJ9tYzHa10VA3alqrtVHD48aWpqsWda5rn@x5V0WLE1mZyHGisJup@KfeTBsq/2j0T9PoZX5taTdqAyCAqWn8WQxQNaaNP3z4QN8P46uxaPGGePdh3rn8wBv4XD0w9n4DO0VEXqYUpgVyzRFbr2lI9D1tfUPdKm3n/5pPNZAvV5UqyJeVgjRTWNMuELtSwai/le2KrJAC61S0igPPCJBOV7clGR@pee5d@JHUaN1IiDznyCbGbNNCZhEETsLifv@p5PiiC1EU2w/swFMvCGgfR0nkOE6C3hiJDcFhS50wh/7PAdZWmnr4hMeON/K88Wg09uafF36643z5glyJ/B4ioSUZFLUqle2t2tZ2tbJV3treWq/ZG7Va2a6U7c2tzW2rDMe3ZW9s1bbt8tb6dnV9fX0bvbXtTangRT2/b5rwMLYsM95AvkW/pGjQb05iY9BiUqHn9amQ92So9jRW6M1fjLaYXN3qWGeyRD8xYirc7w0tFZWlSIzivsqs8gimVdsdbckbm/LOGu7yrlxFc6haigVvr3RkWWtvd3flzZq8I29uykyry5tyfQpyZmzOCWVYMobB8NV1ifpFIFHlTRi3UgdYXQz5p6UxyeUO9rsJJd0cHDnpxrZMrwHSaNXO13bKtl7ea7TEdGzDlgpTqUfHsuvbdXLHU/QVFeJSqUoFvRqvx4VisQjvfdqSq/KR0TBzv9wyuV/ukJ8mx2hITWAhqynIBTbxF38dAX7r3f/@L06J9kL6La7Z36Of64WdoVJdV6qdZkG4BHtTK7Qqm0bqXBe64h1T1zeh2W6Bu5KKXeiP@We@EO8ty6XWiufxVcjDFMjY@kPv4sKv/OHN52/YqigK4r@98V1viL8GLi@OBF3yRk3WYP5p@uns0xlCZ43JlZrMWMlk2PCY/1qBnW9vb2xtFKRfTfOxrQ5655la30MSMwpXpWr7if/GodpSNE/X0HgzQk4/XweMFgIlwYPW7Xd8cdx6xf8XCt5JRBeZikoN@HK3zAtebI379a7GbmbFUpV6qV6nzct7iZeNkohZdVGGpSn8@rwJLLS0WJMAeDUO3lv1m3ad@Q2aDHckdDkG@sxGlJrUpI0Ep8LvanVpuW7JKWlh9BItS@NLJQE@FWQJftywJ9gWffNHkBfS@Y6r5qO1OwBtqwsYpWMpOZu/hQ1k7Op8hjL73WzcGY/cVZvxxElYdObvF6qYSmtZOaxLxPbasC79SXW1G8qp69/DZ8/cT8N22K1rYTOje6kU1qfSpeoLkLWsGTZ1uz4EsfWsXSr53Wao/UkdcuLDpgVg4KaZU@1mrumomasr1cpf25H@PeqWD9tRye6WR@W1j82vZadplSf4QmzloPwLhDcTpZo1v5aiutPAl9L7W5IYNtOSU79dTsaQSzVofm073aal1QMMLJUOwQzoTNtBqdTVgDxA5/2B9eDZM6cUtCb1QNc1gvpU3T1sZ2h0S0163lGdxmT3a3uE8Tsq7k2gCTQQj3G3dYD5QF8dMhbqW5AuaJwQeROQFzabax931z6uNZ8@/dqe6GG3LMS/Yy0UT8RPiPhlG1HXPi4bFhcJP@9R5Z/8nZ@MtZTJZVgfhFweLo0UFK59RM9wsRqm/wM)

Languages that are not on TIO:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use python 2. Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse (#73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway (#74) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98 (#76) [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Note that flags must be `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98. Could also be installed via pip.

Languages that use abstracted interpreters in the test driver:

- V (#2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)
- Alphuck (#44) [local](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master)
- What (#71) [local](https://github.com/gimmetehcodez/what/blob/master/what.c)

Other languages:

- Japt (#7) was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Surface (#66) [local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip). Tio Surface interpreter is no contest because it was created after challenge was started.

### Explanation

#### Adding C++14

I am using [digit separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Digit_separators) to separate C++14 from C++11.
See also: [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html).

```
#define s(x) #x // stringize
puts( s(0'0  "'\"")[9] ? "C++11" : "C++14" );
```

C++11 sees 4 tokens: `0`, `'0  "'`, `\`, `""` and puts them in a string as is. C++14 sees 2 tokens: `0'0` and `"'\""`. Two spaces between these tokens are collapsed
into one, so resulting string is one char shorter than in C++11.

I also tried using comments: `s(0'0/*'*/)`. C++14 sees it as token `0'0` followed by comment; comment is replaced with space, which is then discarded (because it is trailing). C++11 sees it as sequence of 4 tokens (`0`, `'0/*'`, `*`, `/`), nothing is replaced/discarded. But I cannot use it because multiline comment breaks assembler. If use single-line comments instead:

```
s(0'0//'
)
```

then closing paren needs to be padded with 13 bytes to satisfy Prelude, which is 
more bytes than just using a string.

#### Fixing other languages

Prelude, incident and alphuck broke as a result.
Prelude and incident are fixed as usual. Spaces around `main()` are for prelude. Space after `<stdio.h>`, tab before `p(d)`, space after `"77"` are
there to break unwanted incident tokens. Macro parameter called `d` also for that reason, to untokenize `#d`. `"7";` is there to untokenize `"7`.

Alphuck is fixed by naming macro `p` and adding another `p` to `ajjap` (seems like number of s and p should match for [alphuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Alphuck) to work).

#### C vs C++

As someone who worked with a processor with `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) == 1` ([TMS320C33](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru034h/spru034h.pdf),
 search for "A TMS320C3x/C4x Byte Is 32 Bits"),
 I didn't feel very comfortable with separating C from C++ using `sizeof('p')`.
So I decided to search for another method, hopefully not too much more verbose than existing one.
I found this: in [the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), 
par C.1.4 page 1232 "Change: The result of a conditional expression, an assignment expression, or a comma expression may be an lvalue"

```
char arr[100];
sizeof(0, arr)
```

yields 100 in C++ and sizeof(char*) in C

Luckily, we already have an array - `u8`. Also we already have redundant use of it to satisfy incident (see `u8;` after `puts(p);` in the previous answer). So we can just put that into use. I only changed its size from 4 to 5 bytes because 4 is a common pointer size.
So to separate C++ from C I use `sizeof(0,u8)-5`. It should work on all architectures except those were `sizeof(void*) == 5`.

Comment: RIP online Japt testing please unfix (or provide a flag for enabling broken behavior or something)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I don't quite understand what you want me to do. I personally also don't like that we use interpreter bug (seems unfair to me) and ended up in this situation. But I can't see how it could be fixed.

Comment: Ask (whoever makes Japt) to add a flag reintroducing the parser bug so we can pretend we're using an earlier version.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I don't want to solve this problem, at least at the moment. If you want this done you could ask him yourself.

Comment: Not interested enough :/

Comment: @CalculatorFeline IMHO, testing with the standalone online interpreter isn't too large a penalty.

Comment: Wait what? I don't recall ever fixing the parsing bug... EDIT: Ohhh, I made a change which broke apart the comment marker (`/*`). Huh. Sorry about that...

Comment: I haven't looked at this for ages, but congrats on finding a better way to distinguish C and C++! (I was the person who originally added C).

Comment: @Muzer Thanks, but I switched back to `sizeof'c'` later.

Answer (score 11):

## 18. Cardinal, 137 bytes

```
#v`16 "<" 6/b0\ .q@#;n4"14""
#>3N9@15o|R"12"*^*ttt*~++%
#=|
print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62);# =#;print(17)
#gg99ddi2` |1|1+6
```

Literal escape chars between `#` and `g`, and `2` and `` ` ``.

Prints:

- 1 in [Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 2 in [V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 3 in [Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 4 in [><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 5 in [Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 6 in [SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 7 in [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYgIjwiIDYvYjBcIC5xQCM7bjQiMTQiIgojPjNOOUAxNW98UiIxMiIqXip0dHQqfisrJQojPXwKcHJpbnQoKDEvMmFuZCA5IG9yIDEzKS0oMGFuZCs0KV4xPDw2NT4+NjIpOyMgPSM7cHJpbnQoMTcpCiMbZ2c5OWRkaTIbYCB8MXwxKzY=&input=)
- 8 in [Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 9 in [Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 10 in [Befunge 93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 11 in [Befunge 98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 12 in [Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 13 in [Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 14 in [Turtléd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 15 in [Haystack](https://tio.run/#couDj)
- 16 in [Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#Jcq9CoMwEADgPa/gctxRMIZWL8aU4A8@QYfORWwRxCW2EjqFvrotdPzg2@k9sgVsEGz@KG5wevVUe4NsEAV15cX1XK3xiqwxG7IQQvZR6iCojeK5LT6kKef67idwsG7ApTymxY/KyIGbxlZdZ7WsCVqq/5/PUlAyz85N06KTESJHVnbfvw)
- 17 in [Julia](https://tio.run/#MUf9S)
- 18 in Cardinal (No online interpreter, but the specs are [here](https://github.com/m-lohmann/Cardinal))

---

Edit: Fixed esc character between `o` and `|` - don't know why it was there in the first place.

Comment: Bytes cannot be fractions, so the limit was really `floor(128 * 1.2)`, so good thing you didn't need another byte.

Comment: Also, this is incorrect, as it prints `6\x00` in SMBF. (There are two `.` characters.)

Comment: Can we get the SMBF to modify out the second period?

Comment: Oh right, forgot about the second period. Shoot.

Comment: @Pavel The modification would have to occur *before* it is executed. So, you could either put in a literal `\x00` byte next to the period and use `[<]` to move to it, then `>+` to modify it, or you have to use way too many `<<<<<<<<<<<<` etc to get there. Considering that you're already at the byte limit, it's not likely to happen without some golfing.

Comment: Will probably delete this answer and add this language later, after I've fixed this. (Unless you all want to keep it up for a while longer. Feel free to suggest edits)

Comment: @MistahFiggins Delete it for now. I suggest trying to use a different character for console output or using the `.` that was already there.

Comment: I could probably use the west instead of east to use the period already there. On my phone now, will do later.

Comment: Is this going to be fixed soon, or should it be deleted for the time being? (Note that a post's author can see and edit it even after it's deleted, so you won't lose your work, although obviously you might have to adapt it to fit in more answers.)

Comment: @ais523 It was deleted for a little while, but it should be fixed now. As far as I know, it works with all 18 languages...

Comment: Broken code. Doesn't work for Minkolang... (The addition of ESC literal causes `9@` to jump to `"`, causing an infinite loop)

Comment: It works for Minkolang with the most recent fix now. I just tested myself to make sure.

Answer (score 11):

## 29. [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 292 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(: ::T): :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#`<`|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and (9) or (13))-(0and 4)^(1)<<(65)>>62)or'(\{(\{})(\{\/+23!@=}[()])}\{})(\{}\{})'#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#]#echo 5+5+11#|/=1/24=x=90/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6$//''25  #>say 27#T222999"26
```

This program prints [**29** in Trigger](https://tio.run/nexus/trigger#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**28** in Brain-Flak](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**27** in Perl 6](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**26** in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), **19** in Reng (tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**9** in Perl 5](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**7** in Japt](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), [**2** in V/Vim](https://tio.run/nexus/v#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LY1NT8JAFEX3/QtshnmavkejwzzagYFO07ULF8qOjxQFkcS0WhuCse1fx6rk3pybnM09wzHTRslYGvV0@5FKnIrpdE4dkZkeYZaHUofSg2R0b1IdFXUi1oOqqgZtELRte@2Ba/O7@EFqljMPFh5kcVZ77@UhrxB3x80bSr088QtL2uRbgZZEUQrUI6IbHP6qkNaoKY7RRJQkhqkofVx@d22ow1IFPOqnrlkgrai52L/1IQ0NTgJ7ieuTg/9rPSZYwe75tRBREAVaQ62cVhy6k7ND5cGkt93vD9zLRK1rc6WU73MkBCSfmy/BY5gzs7VWsjmffwA).

Something must have been working in my subconcious in the time since the last submission to this challenge, because by the point I decided it was running low on time and I wanted to ensure it wouldn't die, I suddenly remembered a language from years back that could be added fairly easily as seen by the low increase in the byte count, and quite a bit of that was due to Hexagony rather than Trigger itself. Except for commands that assign to variables (which mostly don't matter), all Trigger's commands contain two consecutive equal characters. The first time this happens is in the Underload code in the first line, so I simply modified that a bit to jump to almost the end of the program, and placed the Trigger code to print 29 (which is `222999`) there. The jump label I used is `T` (originally I tried `U` but Fission disliked it), but if you need to use a capital `T` in your own program for some reason, you can easily change both occurrences to something else that isn't used in your program.

Very little else needed changing, apart from (as always) the Hexagony. I decided it was time to stop messing around with formatting the code into a hexagon by hand, but luckily we've already had [a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66708/62131) about Hexagony parsing, so I went and modified [this answer to the challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66723/62131) into an online-usable Hexagony formatter that handles backticks correctly ([here](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LU9Nb@JADL3nV0wzXjJm2pgZIG1IJuLcwx62qlSJUEghpazYpJsgRBWSv84ObGXLH09@9vO52ZWrbAcUwcLESdTWNFum9ZxoEzUCduaLiFaYCPgwSg77UkLRF1DcKcRer8rXZQu1gYXv@d7RDt3BDqP3shKQGSgiyGIBa6P7V4ZtpcTGErqa/AaylqCXFnRrkSo/5FWdC6jR0tnA91VrJf0utwXQ7Z/ssxEe844se6sv52Er5UWDD4uLgI7SJ2kl1zYTg54tP6ttsT@f@WGpAnJjN6A3/@/UFRM2mTyjjUJrfOJRMXLVyHV4MvwZTNW4PCXstb/f7/udlF3X/XC46YrH@JertBs5fObwZbw8Odf1QuSHbCdclR71u3YxK9ZMhMjsA0INEe/E4AKN8FUojGMRjDFJAo1l5Ym0sd6iDSlJPbyZ8nYmcI7tN3rNHp@OAvEgw28zN2j4/9PqHvmc56uPko3lWCrFT2QU6ZE5mnBADn94WW82W/2yZCd1CoDI8/SYMZ7U2RfT9/xZax2GoauDfw)). Here's how this version of the program looks as a hexagon:

```
         # v 1 6 / " < " 6 /
        b . q @ " ( : : : U )
       : : ( 2 2 ) S # ; n 4 "
      1 4 " # > 3 N 6 @ 1 5 o |
     > ^ * t t t * ~ + + ~ ~ ~ %
    # = ~ n J < R " 1 2 " ; # [ #
   < | p r i n t ( ( e v a l ( " 1
  \ x 2 f 2 " ) a n d ( 9 ) o r ( 1
 3 ) ) - ( 0 a n d 4 ) ^ ( 1 ) < < (
6 5 ) > > 6 2 ) o r ' ( \ { ( \ { } )
 ( \ { \ / + 2 3 ! @ # } [ ( ) ] ) }
  \ { } ) ( \ { } \ { } ) ' # @ 4 6
   ( 8 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + = ! ) = #
    p r i n t ( 1 7 ) # ] # e c h
     o 5 + 5 + 1 1 # | / = 1 / 2
      4 = x = 9 0 / # 8 ␛ d g g
       i 2 ␛ | 1 | 6 $ / / ' '
        2 5 # > s a y 2 7 # U
         2 2 2 9 9 9 " 2 6 .
```

You might well have noticed that the Nim code is more verbose than it used to be. This is purely because padding it out as `5+5+11` rather than `21` happened to make the Hexagony line up perfectly; if you start at the `/` of `/+23!@#`, you can see an uninterrupted run of Hexagony-safe characters, and that's how I made that part of the program work.

Comment: +1 for the updated hexagony formatter. Are there any online resources for testing in Trigger? I think it may have blown out my next solution. :P

Comment: @Chance: Not yet, although I put in a request for it on TIO. Also, I'd be both surprised and upset if Trigger ended up blocking a language, because it's fairly easy to work into a polyglot; it doesn't parse code you jump over, and its jumping ability is fairly flexible.

Comment: Yeah, I've been digging into some turing tarpits with limited character sets, which had a lot of repeated characters as you'd expect. I'll read up about Trigger's jumping ability though. Maybe it is workable.

Comment: @Chance: The `: ::U` in the current program jumps to the `U` at the end. Everything in between won't even be parsed, so you can repeat as much as you like there.

Comment: `/+23!@=` `!=` `/+23!@#`

Answer (score 11):

## 39. [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), 828 bytes

```
#  1"16" 3//v\(@#/;n4"14"
#/*`3 auaaZ<>16/"<"6/b.q@")(22)S#  ␉␉␉␉ 
#yy␉;36!@
### ␉
#=␉>
#[#yy#yy0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#`<`␉|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and( 9 )or(13 ))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);;}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>3N.<>␉//
#xx
#x%~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#xx
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  ap
#_~nJ|#o51\   
#0␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>#>27.say# =#print(17)###^_^_7LEintndus({})!<>+]/*///Z/}23!@222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#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@/mtyrXfEGlwAGew5TgxqkuYdSZ1Oh@E79XrOILlVgFWBViLixOPMAWaaZGBvtbKuqvY4WiNLGg8sseY/BVQAW5D3nJxUpFx@niQMXKxUSi8hchTzAbQJUZOcC21wsuvCAH7Mg7RC2BV0FvPCQvFE6vd4GMJkqTAI7UE91BeaL3xfqhPeD8@b63NBN42jXMLhZJoJ94NOcFRgfN8nJ6RPw0gcwXuBquA6YWkeZeJMzgNh91HIWWCTBRt@HAigUXwFchRI5QbCZbQWZJIpAMMMsRRVvPrP3/4eDAbAc@D7cRLMnfWEBLGfj8AwlcxSOKJw15jTSLIFuIqgXhwHgSsahQHNBHk@m5OQTEiqkziPAhKDYDIJEVhDeoVg7PeZn7HCxeM8A48VMqKXRWoIC7@F4CPag2ElAUlbim2R/bewks8Kh7FGedb/iljjNimlzrnx@pXx@lmHgTfTNrd1xxnU4W32ttzCU@nXHOfkYGVPRbjPAemzCYkoH@R0ABFjjgPU99k4m@sWOkozaO9hgMhNax7tdjpU9P2HlKXXz/PAGg3hl0UkzmOXCoX48WgEY1gR7E9oMpA2IkGYQJPR7CF1AFw9IK5eCJB7DFyoT7CwSFnwcDZlfp7BEKxCJsPQH5KJ5I4Xpizi5iF5bK1ThzNa/SVpwYzXel5VbGe5Jdh4EoUlDP0YD/KBQNW6tyF9Yn1DCiiT8pEoCPDiRQYWUbKqEkvhoY1vRX5J2E85tItgDQdcgFC@zN5rDh6mvISID9MQKhJ5OMSb4/c/iLD@AytKEZRUpKT1mIxRmHB8nmfFi4XGFOYPY2JxUprzYKgyLX4GW06a@HJhrdUC1bShLkOoTb5aIPpcVNaHeZG0HsNJkqUKOVXVswpSUZTC3jyPIjzkXAaEwcxrOIbP0tSGdyNubVFUwJ1aZubtfcBsmMQTwm7NemkTOWmQY8j8AemXfAiROeM@kvWqiMuSPxXlqqOo41k2jHntvveqqzfVom6cOCOKSBzPNke0uo5KHvgu5JexsLwzWqy6ru3t3EOBluPxyX6YDuXlHugjth6/kafTUa8vLxsAuHCtB/qSL0Yxjwvi0FDIqfNR3mxE6CYO7gfCPfJvGEw1YNZezemF3Omx/lOQ7968eS9h@r1e@BQQ1CA6q8V9A1iS9zZpqUfT4aNESe7p@ThPssgKnEzc2b//FEDfj60xpLMUtfRyuehyNhGWsfpPGmd@VDzIy2ZDfs4j9Fm/gcOnon7SaLnYjOsV@cjg7ahvXLZX4DSKEI5QGRLGY3dGJER5wBb3zUilDu/nW8LDkagXY9H4PnHiQYEoCIoWI4liGjhF0xeylfUKPbMpHcR85qwlHzvp/Q9sLXI4WXV52TDP8uIqWrvfslM4Ft9fC7c5pLtz8MZrz29PwIOJ3af8tAiRBJnEehfRS6cnlt0@lptFLYRJwgH6yMX9KTCWyiRj9eL40ip699RBWUV3M6Y@k6G2etzoQ9@hNEdo34@@/3R0@KvOJCkCWxIV143o3nMfFYtnv40Jaojk5X/0QnlIOopPI8u1a64jJi9rTYfhA61HtDcTo8Lw/3cwQXFQLhMrXnX4q8FuPH76kO9vPlSMfvKcH6Nj3WAOWcY@yrlh2a5haCjGHeyFyby9TZcTpLZ6SzhF14W6J9aL/qNedMDpUDbOaHQDBPEnHsqOA4160e9VSA89hEyO//pnMJ8nBixLyShM0S8PuJiA0dQN48lrSbdolt8eHBELnbLkoU/UL62XbqpWiH7w8ZuTU/esRFR9qs4ZFQOR7P@XDBfCEEOsD2WBmbeoIzlLSZnYRLaomJ8wOomyK4YUtEUpps/MlKgNJNUROh/rKCM7YoJnGTrcnfnURcRMDEoSlOhTcoNxlgbE8om34@KpECUSHf@ouapl6@2D8zXr5TIQMTdWa00pBwbTRkuuEhbEYiw4Pe8EZ0660Abm0S/d6lTo47kjTIEZ9lq3W@7NTUpnqnpbMteG/PYUjQXiRQxbclhSxOAvVBXn2b0GfhJmw6LTRPvpD6noR0QDuugaBUt9JAMSQU4xBMnoT4WgRCjTJgdRilk8CKCm3iwT2s15VjSKy25R1Qi3l35UIary6NcKcTaFwrPFBIuxKkkkD0NUzcKrYJggBthEzm9oS9H42ratTHxhAoli0@iFeR4zYTFudTKs/zxf97H@a7E@d4RJnUczWCHII/2tZcLwXozNJd/ABQGxf2xggmP9l2J92nGtu7NNo@ADNtZNCPrz4ofQFD9BAOot3CjMXpH93zHO2YwY8KMRTTAg5ihHiVlZ/PxVWY6sj9lul66jGAlSd@rSP@u34PCiQzpZp9/hgs36zPnCsZ36taFHzZnjOL7ZMvRh0yvXtstlnW8bOrc803z@XLj1rZ429a6t2uoUQJYemXU4qKHTps7rOm0YetCsbssTeCyXzWscuMOEfK3TW0d/Dk1VsJOwK3goM/TUFI24a9veLfj7HIdcdyojOr42VKJOxQ8ggrwelsuCB1vvCgbunM5RGZxD8UeODKb63PjOYFSX4Va6r/pfftEI8VRvVyU1x7nqGPuaU@cvVO@FqmjO9kUNSqX0x0bL23XUhrrr9Oyf9lXTqFbNI5zcwoco2my2Va/tPtuX8bmlaM2tlqKdYhv/buSOpq536V1iFU7dz1N36A69wPO8Q5d9cntTt@fGXoArw587xTJ0@1N34HKXe97UjbHwp66PRR/XgXjVB5LP@AtdV@AWJEZu5MmP6xrnXVPRLhoXWzeKlNow2BWNDNXrTKv9qmoi8g2yR0xYyKsR07QMVySDF@a512gYuztmq2XsVk28Lxmda/zfmuJyaphn5i0Wxb9Z0l7sGl@V9@Z/zWemJhi4aTpNz6m@aE6be6cNvbxftvbxabbKjfnttdYq25ZlnzlKt/v1wfFBt9v0NMdRNLtjq15V3d4SuqzLFB5HzI7iASG1PUXFR8A1e2wQ8i1xYhvfgPWRr7Z@Jpiaf2YobSW/ZHmv1dpX6iu19hK2DLkvmtmGaPtje9hSRKSJsc0w4R0Ch2FeaBed0rZzLQqn8bNZr98626WLC0UvCcCSpGbV4hexpuu60mjVvrcbLbk7neL75d3dXXmrfLedZdm2PZW7TfGLKooagATnknfNPdNk8qxCZKNz@u7gbcVrWFpVLo4@vdHE087qsYrHmnj80P6m/bHd/mPFO/zQPjhqf/P@pP3psFhDDDpWtO4d//ZGi3e8DsiC1BfBYBBWv4AneDe7uuOUStUdgtG4pbWqL22UF400tcJHvJcmdH7ePe@@/NDGBg/y1ICVnzVa5TOoyHF@dG6rtWf71Wp1b29Pre7@Fw)

### Rundown

This program prints **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required.

Here is yet another evolution of the Incident [tokenizer](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#ZVT/d9o2EP8Z/wv9RVhpkCyDJUNIiS2HLCN9W7O@vnXZ28M44IABN7ahYDqHBP717gS0rNvp291Jd/fR6ctXy0LXi2gU5xeoPY6ixXKVIjJfxGm4eELhKp/OFtRE7etpmA0jYH5braOFhuNsmKxGEXKX@Sie1abeD6pFnE2UTouzHKVhnBH6rCGg4TRcoDibr3JfcKDAOaqHs2wY/qj/exonERlPonxJdlYmEtxumEhFzWhZvr@7vaW7pYogMHgge0fmPg7dexoftCBuNCM3U0dTQY25o70jQ/o8ni2Is01PT4f3cz8NHJrKXI2Mpc5GeyTxfomRy1RWhTP348DJfcbiQKb0HVEydVLJYTGEUp6Xhy2rFGQSoCVRRpbUXPtZdZsF5o2fMRGYK9PoyrUZSm4W0GIpzMT8LMUBNsTM5ZplTuhCY@zg9BvN5ZKFzg8qZfJIErn2w0By6iRgyNgNbAZwLv2EsYBC8AQm/2/oJKenIUu8wkmqVapW3dcvb/wcmIBJJV@Q0C0u1/4K7C8IjBLCJBTAg90h2Zvv2AGfAzneH9ER@h5joeAVAC@V0uheGl1Dlstrv6imgblP/wU/Hq4CXyjwR9TxmBhdiv6TErh8@Zjor@OL1zVj2ct0M2YMsmzO/2W6h2h0YWbO2DfYm69fMUJCF00d1S3rS4@0seVkDV00dA1bxqAOTyIMu64nmpbu6k3rofa5rVNi2/QjWJaAkIafnkpOvVluaxhjVNKwLMHz8EENlSc8Lbh4FI/AxQX/VPApn4qREOIDj@74Q8Ef@EyMoI@g8ALYmI8LPuEZz4Qo@AyYYcGHwIyhn6ipMTj5BCWGtwO@VYiUJ2JHnJP7PtXwwB2UXrRdegiJvoQJ0UWvsMe2TsNsRFALUTgWUUeUVgkHFWrQe@G6pHlGPY80bQrzFdJ7hrqhqvMJDegGmH2lFdxokjesdSiyTLEC8CItKSy7IQvZ8t0T1mbVNpD0mHsYLrHHatVqLbC0fv/nqz@u@n0psGVpuNar6cLWjZLKpaP@iOUsiWrJbIJQvaXpQGqdfIgmcVZSFga0UTSOs6i0hi8hXkezMaoMK1Vxqdff6Bd6/Vz//lkdv6/jT4WQpXwQOsCDXsWwnuEXWZI1dZyNZVQGA@2kohZWdtGq9Vljhk9OTjTXq7@vud5OWxTQXm@3W1ZiWyPPc6NW7LQygrQipCAr5DvsmAc4Gk5nyIYtk55/c3VtCreK7R3z8e4nrKSzo2iDWFfibedt5/dO5y9TfLjtXH3svP3lz87dhz0P2wjnGu5vs19f8OxM9CAshHo1mkxi@xXcBPHSPLGsSsU@Q8jzPOzZ57Vl@ISRxPs7Is4p5Py@f98/v@2AIhutlgROuex6LIAUWVbX2tj1ctu27VarpdvNfwA), I reworked it so the polyglot can be put directly to input and removed the linefeed replacing format from the test driver since it was no longer needed.

Edit: Thanks to @SnoringFrog to pointing out how to fit CoffeeScript into the test driver. Link is updated.

### Explanation

This answer came directly from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101159/tips-for-creating-polyglots/101189#101189) general polyglot tip by @Sp3000 where I learned that Coffeescript used `#`  based comments, and a different block comment indicator than all the other languages we’ve used so far. @Sp3000’s example didn’t have the output going to STDOUT though. So I took a quick trip over to the PPCG Hello, World! Collection and found that @Lynn provided an example [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/55576#55576) that *was* closer to my STDOUT tastes.  Sweet.

Here are the CoffeeScript syntactic highlights:

- `# This is a line comment`
- `### This is a block ###`
- `""" This is a literal string"""`
- `console.log 39 # This is the STDOUT print statement`

There were only a couple quirks with CoffeeScript that I had to work out. First, the print statement really needed to live behind a `#` to hide from the other languages, but the statement seemed to want to be on its own line. This was eventually resolved by throwing a `;` between the end of the comment block and the print statement.

Second, the block comments seem fail on the C/C++lines. I’m not sure why exactly, but my guess is something to do with the `/*` comments.  (CoffeeScript is used to programmatically generate JavaScript which uses `/*` comments. /Shrug. ) In any event, I found that I could use Python’s syntactically matching literal string to hide this code more effectively. So I simply dropped out of the block comment earlier than I had planned to print 39 and everything else was just magically hidden from CoffeeScript. Great Success!

### The Few Things I Did Break

Retina didn’t like the line I inserted for `console.log  39`, so I needed to remove a line for Retina’s rule of even numbers. Maybe I just made that rule up, or maybe it’s legit. It feels legit. Anyways, there was already a do nothing line in the Python string. So I just removed that. This changed the value of Retina’s output, but that was easy to fix by throwing a few more 1’s in the long Python print statement. So far so good.

Hexagony’s  hex got bumped up to the next size, so I had to resolve that. But first, the new Hexagony module `/(3!@)` , while super effective, made my Prelude sense tingle. I didn’t like the idea of having to move this all the time for Hexagony’s alignment and then having to redo Prelude’s vertical parenthetic alignment. So I dug in and found a new Hexagony module that didn’t have this poly-linguistic baggage: `/}23!@`.

Incident, in all these tweaks lost its singular left side *incidental* token. (Get it? Cuz it’s not used by Incident… Never mind). The easiest solution to re-balance Incident’s center token turned out to be CoffeeScript’s block comment. So, I added the 3rd `###` just prior to final pair of jump tokens (`^_`). This put one unused token on the left side and eight unused tokes on the right side. (Eight minus one is lucky number seven.) This also happened to align the hexagon so the Hexagony module could be nested in Trigger’s code like so: `Z/}23!@222999`.

Whitespace was the last piece of broken code, but it was not too difficult rebuild. It was just a matter of removing lines from the end until it worked, and then putting them back one by one and figuring out if I should make it a triple space line, a tab line, or a no whitespace line.

Good Luck.

Comment: Nice one! There are definitely more things that can be done with #-initiated multi-line comments, I think.

Comment: @Muzer Thanks. Yeah, I decided go into some # space since you've been having so much success with the C variants. Looking forward to your next.

Comment: `coffee polyglot.poly` is all you need to add it to the driver, at least that worked for me

Comment: @SnoringFrog And of course it's the easy solution I didn't bother to try. Thanks!

Comment: "Retina’s rule of even numbers" → Retina has two parsers, and (in the common case where lines don't contain the backquote character) alternates which one it uses from one line to the next. One is a lot more tolerant than the other one, so making sure that complex lines end up on the tolerant parser is likely going to be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

## 40. [Minimal-2D](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minimal-2D), 902 bytes

```
    #  1"16" 3//v\(@#/;"14"\Dv
#/*`3 auaaZ<>16/"<"6/b.q@")(22)S#  ␉␉␉␉ 
#yy␉;36!@
### ␉
#=␉>
#[#yy#yy0l0mx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10mx0m0l11111100(^_)
#`<`␉|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and( 9 )or(13 ))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);;}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>3N.<>␉//
#xx\"R++++++++++++++++++\"++++++++++++++++++.----.
#x%~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#xx++U++++++++++++++++v<L>4n;
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  ap
#_|#o51~nJ\   
#0␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  >>>#>27.say# =#print(17)###^_^_7LEintndus({})!<>+]/*///Z/}23!@222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVhJd9vGHT8LXyGXMYCYgEhspCVH5mLJtpznxElUS3b7ImoZAkMSFjhgsIhktLxe29dD77302O/Raz9Fv0j6mwFXkUpSSAQGwH/@@4pfNHGQozia9KI4IxlLMxIk4TVLbPJqQvZpmO5Ua4oioZI4yP2Q90jWZyTkwzwj3TBiqeLTjLTIcIrFFguikYTRoABTunFCxBYyuIpISPzhkHQi2rd9gKXxQLzKWDJMGM4p4YwFJB0yP@yGviRB2DhjPA1jntok9K/IKIwiErAIGxZ0/QqQkTxdelRQsZUgVggOf/iAy/mdzgDD2UxSNqSJlDQmQyn2TOBRQodDMKlo5BiMZ@GApSTMSilhNA2F@rAlZTyQShrOFRsTypelJNchJRT85onEnbIkg3i2xEv6LGFASQXxXkIHxBglYQYVCB0ekCNGE3KSMGaCCnTPUp8OwccKSRCLBYVMCGJLGzUapcMf3pZgq2KHTYeZoiW1kz98o1BiN4l@Ucevqap15fD7N@RGb4s1uAAy2HOYGNQkzXuSOu02w2/sdZxecqcAqwKtRMSJh5kDzDTJwN5iZV1X7WG0RJY0HlhiyX8KqAC2IO84@VSRcvl5kjBwsVApvYLIUcx70CZETXIutMHJrgsD@DEP0gph19BZzAsLxSOp35N@CJOlwiC0A/VQX2i@8H2pTng/PG@qzxndNI5yCYedaSbcDzrBVoHxXZd8Il0aRmIL3gtUBdcJS/MoE3tyHgi7D0LOApvM2PDjQAAN4muQo0AqHyBcBktBJpkCMMwQS1HFq//@/R9Brwc8B74fJ8HUWT@RIPbzARimklkKRxTuGnMaSbYAVxHUi@0gcE2jMKCZIM8nUxKSCUl1FOdRQGIQTEYhAqtPrxGM3S7zM1a4eJxn4LFCBvSqSA1h4bcQfEA7MKwkIGlLsS2y/xpW8lnhMNYgz7pfEWt4SEqpc268fGG8fNJm4M20zW3dcXp1eJu9LR/hrvRrjvPpYGFPRbjPAemyEYko7@W0BxFjjg3U99kwm@oWOkozaO9hgMiH1jTa7bSv6PsPKUuvn@aBJRrCL4tInMYuFQrx48EAxrAi2J/QpCdtRIIwgSajyUPqALh@QFy9FCArDFyqj7AwS1nwcDZmfp7BEKxCRv3Q75OR5I4Xpizi5iF5PFqmDme0unPSghmv9bSq2M78kWDjURSWMPQ6HuQDgaq18kD6xPIDKaBMyseiIMCLZxlYRMmiSsyFhza@EfklYT/l0C6CNexxAUL5PHsvOXiY8hIiPkxDqEjk4RBvTt79IML6j6woRVBSkZKWYzJGYcL2aZ4VL2YaU5jfj4nFSWnKg6HKtPgZbDlp4suFtVQLVNOGugyhNvlqhuhzUVkf5kXSWoeTJEsVcqqqZxWkoiiFvXkeRbjJuQwIg5k3cAyfpakN70bc2qKogDu1zMy7VcCsn8Qjwu7MemkTOWmQE8j8HumXvA@ROeMukvWiiMuSPxblqq2ow0nWj3lt1XvVxZtqUTc@OQOKSBxONke0uoxKbvgu5FexsLwzmK0uXNvbWUGBlmN9ZzdM@/K0ArrG1vobuTsddLrytAGAC9d6oC/5YhDzuCAODYWcOh/kxUaEbuJgNRBWyL9iMFWPWXs1pxNyp8O6j0G@ffXqnYTpdjrhY0BQg@isZtcNYEne2aSlDk37a4mSrOj5JE@yyAqcTFzZf/4cQN/r1ujTSYpaejVfXHA2Epaxuo8aZ7pV3MjTZkN@ziP0Wb@Bw6eiftJovtiM6wX5wODtqG9ctlfgNIoQjlAZEsa6OyMSojxgs@tmpFKHq/mW8HAg6sVQNL6P7HhQIAqCosVIopgGTtH0hWxhvULPbEx7MZ84S8nHTjq/g61ZDieLLi/r51lenEVr91t2Cofi92vhNoV0dw5eeYfTyyPwYGL3MT8tQiRBJrHeRvTK6YjlRRfLzaIWwiRhD33k7PoYGEtlkrE6cXxlFb176qCsorsZUp/JUFvcbvSh71CaI7Tvx99/PD76VWeSFIEtiYrzRnTvuI@KxbPfxgQ1RPL0O71QbpKO4tPIcu2a64jJy1rSYfhA6xHtTMSo0P//HUxQ7JXLxIoXHf5isBsOH9/k@5s3FaOf3OfH6FjZY0ZF7QgHELEaLC3XgWXN@yCHjHlvhwmjmI3wLEymvXA6Hze1xVvCKVo0FEmxnjUr9aJdTvuyy0ZXHCDiP/JQtifo6ovmsEI6aDhkJv33v4Lp8NFjWUoGYYrmusfFuIwOsB@PXkq6RWf9@uCYWGirJQ9don5pPXdTtUL0gw9ffzp1z0pE1cfqlFExPclhYc5wIQwxxPpIVqNpPzuQg5eUiY1kP4thC3OWqNFiokEPlWJUzUyJ2kAGHqBNso4zsiPGfZahHd6ZjmhEDNCgJEGJPia3mH1pQCyfeDsu7gpRIjEeDJqLwrfcazhvWCeXUYshs1prSjkwxTZacpWwIBYzxOl5Ozhz0pk2MLx@6VbHQh9PHWEKDLw3ut1yb29TOlHVu5K59EXgcIwuBMElJjM5WSniK4FQVZxnK93@KMz6RVuKXtXvU9G8iG511mIKlrrIHCSCnGJikqkiFYISoUybHEQpBvcggJo6k0xoN@dZ0VXOW0tVI9ye@1GFqMrapw2xN4XCs9m4ixksSSQPfZTYwqtgmCAG2EgOe@hh0SXbtq2MfGECiWLTnIbhHwNkMZu1M6z/Ml13sf5bsT53hEmdtYGtEGRNf0tpM1yJsankG7ggIPbPDUxwrP9arE/brnV/tmlufMDGsglBf1opEZriewWgXsONwuwF2f@Wcc4mxIAfDWiCaTJH7UrMyuxbWWU@366zfVi6iWJkU92pS/@s34HDyzZpZ@1umws26xPnC8d26jeGHjUnjuP4ZsvQ@02vXNsul3W@bejc8kzz6VPh1nd62tQvbNVWxwCy9Misw0ENnTZ1Xtdpw9CDZnVb7sBtuWzeYMM9xukbnd45@lNoqoInCbuGhzJDT03Rtbu27d2Bv89xyHWnMqDDG0Ml6lh8LRHk9bBcFjzY@oVg4N5pH5fBORR/7Mhgqk@N7/QGdRlupVXV//KLRoinersqqTnOddvY15y66j1T22@uFc3ZvqxBq5T@2Gh5u47aUHedjv3Tvmoa1ap5jK1bOIiiTSZb9druk30ZoFuK1txqKdopHuPfjdzB2PWuvCuswrH7eez23b4XeJ535LKPbmfsdtzYC3Bm@HPHWIZud@z2XO5yzxu7MRb@2PWx6OLcE6@6QPIZf6HrCtyCxMCNPHm4rnF@YSraZeNy61aRYhsGu6aRoXrtcbVbVU2EvkH2iAkTeTVimpbhimzwzDz3Gg1jd8dstYzdqon3JaN9g/87U5xODfPMvMOi@DdL2rNd46vy3vSv@cTUBAO3TafpOdVnzXFz77Shl/fL1j6OZqvcmF5eaq2ybVn2maNcXLw5ODm4uGh6muMomt22Va@qbm8JXdZlDo8jZkdxj5DanqLiEHDNDuuFfEvs2MYvYF0krK2fCWbsnxlqW8kvWd5LtfaV@kKtPVcVLeS@aH0bYkiI7X5LEaEmhjzDhHsIHIZ5qV22S9vOjaicxs9mvX7nbJcuLxW9JABLkppVi5/Fmq7rSqNV@95utOTT8bitfiivHW11/RnEhuDY8uX9/X15q3y/nWXZtj0WSMrljw/BrxvvW894XWmKD7koj6AmVCCVoLlnmkzDVejOaJ@@PXhd8RqWVpWL44@vNHG3s7it4rYmbt8ffn344fDwTxXv6P3hwfHh1@8@HX48KtbQBx0q2sWtFu949/ybNsiC1BdBrxdWv4BLebe7uuOUStUdgom8pbWqz20UKo00tcLZvOcmjHd@cX7x/P0hHvAgTw24y5NGq3wGXTvOj85dtfZkv1qt7u3tqdXd/wE)

### Rundown

This program prints **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Minimal-2D is not available on TIO, but a python interpreter is available [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Minimal-2D_interpreter).

Current version of the Incident [tokenizer](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#ZVT/d9o2EP8Z/wv9RVhpkCyDJUNIiS2HLCN9W7O@vnXZ28M44IABN7ahYDqHBP717gS0rNvp291Jd/fR6ctXy0LXi2gU5xeoPY6ixXKVIjJfxGm4eELhKp/OFtRE7etpmA0jYH5braOFhuNsmKxGEXKX@Sie1abeD6pFnE2UTouzHKVhnBH6rCGg4TRcoDibr3JfcKDAOaqHs2wY/qj/exonERlPonxJdlYmEtxumEhFzWhZvr@7vaW7pYogMHgge0fmPg7dexoftCBuNCM3U0dTQY25o70jQ/o8ni2Is01PT4f3cz8NHJrKXI2Mpc5GeyTxfomRy1RWhTP348DJfcbiQKb0HVEydVLJYTGEUp6Xhy2rFGQSoCVRRpbUXPtZdZsF5o2fMRGYK9PoyrUZSm4W0GIpzMT8LMUBNsTM5ZplTuhCY@zg9BvN5ZKFzg8qZfJIErn2w0By6iRgyNgNbAZwLv2EsYBC8AQm/2/oJKenIUu8wkmqVapW3dcvb/wcmIBJJV@Q0C0u1/4K7C8IjBLCJBTAg90h2Zvv2AGfAzneH9ER@h5joeAVAC@V0uheGl1Dlstrv6imgblP/wU/Hq4CXyjwR9TxmBhdiv6TErh8@Zjor@OL1zVj2ct0M2YMsmzO/2W6h2h0YWbO2DfYm69fMUJCF00d1S3rS4@0seVkDV00dA1bxqAOTyIMu64nmpbu6k3rofa5rVNi2/QjWJaAkIafnkpOvVluaxhjVNKwLMHz8EENlSc8Lbh4FI/AxQX/VPApn4qREOIDj@74Q8Ef@EyMoI@g8ALYmI8LPuEZz4Qo@AyYYcGHwIyhn6ipMTj5BCWGtwO@VYiUJ2JHnJP7PtXwwB2UXrRdegiJvoQJ0UWvsMe2TsNsRFALUTgWUUeUVgkHFWrQe@G6pHlGPY80bQrzFdJ7hrqhqvMJDegGmH2lFdxokjesdSiyTLEC8CItKSy7IQvZ8t0T1mbVNpD0mHsYLrHHatVqLbC0fv/nqz@u@n0psGVpuNar6cLWjZLKpaP@iOUsiWrJbIJQvaXpQGqdfIgmcVZSFga0UTSOs6i0hi8hXkezMaoMK1Vxqdff6Bd6/Vz//lkdv6/jT4WQpXwQOsCDXsWwnuEXWZI1dZyNZVQGA@2kohZWdtGq9Vljhk9OTjTXq7@vud5OWxTQXm@3W1ZiWyPPc6NW7LQygrQipCAr5DvsmAc4Gk5nyIYtk55/c3VtCreK7R3z8e4nrKSzo2iDWFfibedt5/dO5y9TfLjtXH3svP3lz87dhz0P2wjnGu5vs19f8OxM9CAshHo1mkxi@xXcBPHSPLGsSsU@Q8jzPOzZ57Vl@ISRxPs7Is4p5Py@f98/v@2AIhutlgROuex6LIAUWVbX2tj1ctu27VarpdvNfwA) for working with Incident.

### Explanation

I couldn't find something I knew that would work, so I googled "2D language" and used the first thing that popped up.

**Minimal-2D** is essentially Brainfuck, except it lacks loops and used UDLR to redirect a pointer around. If the pointer hits an edge of the file, execution terminates. It can probably be golfed down somewhat; if I get a chance before the next answer comes in I'll try to do that.

The `D` on the first line sends the pointer downwards to the `L` in `<L>`, then the rest is dumb, brute force brainfuck to the `U` and `R`. The `++` preceding the `U` is filler to not break **Fission**, and the final `+` on line 22 is **Hexagony** filler.

### Things that broke

**><>** breaks on `D`, so it's code is now redirected downwards. Since I was already extending line 20, I used that to terminate the string that got started, and moved the `>4n;` into line 22. I tried to just use `!` to skip the `D`, but **Turtled** didn't like that.

**Fission** broke in various places, which led to filler characters throughout this process. The `++` before the `U` is all that's left of that now, I think. Those could be changed to whatever is necessary for other languages.

**Perl 6** didn't like my unmatched `>`, so I added in a `<`.

**05ab1e** went a little crazy over my extra quotation mark, so I quoted most of line 20 to appease it.

**Pyth** didn't like the `D` or the quotations, so all of those got escaped (at least I guess that's what happened? I just tossed a `\` before all of them and it worked, so I moved on).

**Hexagony** was broken most of the time. Then at the end it miraculously worked.

**Reng** was apparently broken a few answers back and was outputting a nonprintable character before the 19. That's been fixed now by putting the **Haystack** code before the **Reng**.

**Incident**, by this point, had picked up two new tokens that shifted the center, `v` and `+<`. So I changed my `+<` to `+v<`. Problem solved.

### Scores from [The versatile integer printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)

Just for kicks and going off of @Stewie Griffin's comment on the question, here's a snippet that shows how each answer would have scored if it was entered into "The Verstatile Integer Printer". So far, looks like answer 31 was our best score with a .01094, but still not quite good enough to beat the best VIP score of .009185.

```js
// This was stolen/sloppily hacked together from the snippet here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world. Feel free to clean it up if you'd like.
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 102370; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 8478; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*)[,\(].*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function getScore(langs, bytes) {
  var l = Math.pow(langs,3);
  return bytes/l;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
 
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
        score: getScore(match[1].split(".")[0],+match[2]).toFixed(6),
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link, score: a.score};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.lang_raw.split(".")[0] - b.lang_raw.split(".")[0];
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.score)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Scores from <a href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer">The Versatile Integer Printer</a></h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Fun note: changing the text after `\"` to `++]++++[>+++++++++++++<-]>.---<[-]>.` will get brainfuck to output 41. Didn't have time to fix the problems that causes, but maybe it's a decent starting point for someone; esp with SMBF.

Comment: I think your Tio link's code is different from your submission. Can you update?

Comment: @SnoringFrog I was under the impression that the only way to produce SMBF code that will have a different result in BF, is to rely on undefined behaviour in BF? Even if you have a BF compiler that allows you to go left without UB, I suspect it'll be rather tricky to get them both to behave... perhaps not impossible though!

Comment: @Muzer It'd hinge on the interpreter. Assuming we use TIO, moving left from the start in BF doesn't error out, it's just a no-op. From there it's just getting BF/SMBF to enter/skip different loops than one another. [This](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#bY@xCgJBDET7@YqUypKUVnF@JKQQPeTg3Cv0/8@sh4VgdpOFIZO83eCU5hIWmlRPVAQcKu5ChiSafE/4eFRYjj1N1cpjYriu/bkuky3rvWYoXEwIzP0lj8vcD8ddZclOtH@RjKrBH9ELrNaoD8KBGR8i@zPCmThP/QZk9RVu/WJcgKTsmxvytG1v) does it (kept the line structure of the current program but stripped unnecessary characters). Mixing that w/ the other langs is the issue then.

Comment: @Muzer But I'm not seeing any good/easy way to do that. I'd wager the SMBF needs to be significantly altered to have a chance at making this work with everything else. That line 1 period is annoying.

Comment: I requested that Minimal-2D be added to Tio. And it is there now. :)

Answer (score 11):

## 68. Python (1.6.1), 1698 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@-----x-.+?
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#
#x
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{}) ){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#( prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm 
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005400 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1773 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTrLcttIkufGL/SlDLINgCRepChLAklJtqVZd9strSU/wiQtl8AiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzE/0ptZBb5ESu6O2I1YSAIKqHxVZlZWVpYuaTr8/fcCXuQ08m8GfpSRjKUZ6SXeNUsM8vSGHFAvrVdrksShkqg3cr1wQLIhI14YjzLS93yWSi7NSIvEORUDG6RAEkZ7AkzqRwlBFBJc@cQjbhyTS58ODZf4HodNowD7M5bECYN7SkLGeiSNmev1PZfzIWySsTD1ojA1iOdekbHn@6THfEBYMHcrQIyM0qVPgpUh9SKJwOXGd0SdvxUZwIRsNlwW04QPNyIxH/ts1OOExjEIKRXIGQieeQFLiZcpKWE09VCHgJKysMc1Fc@1GxEaLo@SXHuUUJB3lHDaKUsyGJ7B6ZIhSxiQpMh8kNCAqOPEy0AFqMhDcspoQs4TxjTgAgZgqUtjkGOFJTCLkEOGAzG4oRoN5ejkWAGDCQyDxplUSGrn//qzRInRJMULB/6asuxIR78@J7fFDrZBCiAGRo0TlWqk@Y2kZqfD4G9iX5qDZCoBVQm04hMzijMTKNMkA/EWLf26asT@ElvSuGOJJScSUD2wBXkRkrcVPi53lCQMpFiolF7BkP0oHIA2YajJKERthGTbAgO4UdhLK4Rdg86iUFgoGnP9ng89MFmKBqGXoB7qoubFBODqhCkAnpfrc8Y3jfwRhwPMNEP3A50AKlJ80SdvSZ96PqJAP5ISUicsHfkZ4ozCHto98ELWM8hMDDfqIVAQXQM7CkT5B5gzwdJM40IBMJgh4kPFrn/@9W@9wQDoHLpulPRyZ31LepE7CkBgyoWl4IjorlFIfS4WwFWQu0AHBtfU93o0Q/bhTc6CC8G5jqOR3yMRMEzGHkysIb2GydjvMzdjwsWjUQYyVkhAr0R88ITfwsADegmG5Qw4bz5snRw8Ayu5TDiMHoyy/g7R4yOipOZHdX9P3X/UYSCbZmilomkOHPA2o8Q/wZvykOO8PVzYE73n3ItwFvnxcAQxA3rCNIZokqAyXQrDSTGoZBDzKuSSK5pHInB0PkXHTEkYuYR5PRsY9xHhA4iv47zNKSxsOoNbdTHWW/Iw8E5wsixdCxJ@NAbGXDYMnODTITKnAwqssnxAh2JAgiP/sjq0qxA8HaldMrKjX3pgHfQDCDW5MZbGCOC1qoABasJ6S5MioDdAxRUhemFJ4vXByAH4bXJDXIaTAWYFE3EOmYy4Y6Qe@FHUJ5Zerde/Y/wsMQ/1DybVv5gP2hgHf8fMh6TPxsSn4WBEB@DIUQgo1HVZnOUzCEaSZjBH7oZB/lHPY7qRDqXiwV3ePLbl0X6JB0YfYb08QlN0e1BUAKrWfZjlhCYDPhNJz0tgvvg3d7kDwPUd5vInBFkR4JN8jwizhQmcjE2YO8pguoEjj4eeOwTfRelCMWFFdLzLHj4tc4eQo/fnrFEYu/W4Khnm/BOKcS8JHS26TgeiPpJqrXzgxl/@8DBlmgYbCEdzESFCLX01TGqA7@VKg9X8DDMJCH@zpZvPrHl6MdcnKPhnXJgS9tsIDAb@7A1CBKHhfNlfioxeGiqwVHipB1rHBRx9/fzFCa4H75jIYUDvYi1bDuYRZDSAni/Q2DEzgsTcYUT0kCi5DKrM19PPIJaZJi5v6EtJhKwZoCcV9cW7ZoQ@i7zs7oJKWutwnKVSIW1Z7lZgDfNTcKFw5PvwMgr5FFOZdgu@5rI0NWDCgG4NzEZAOrnMtOkqYDZMojFhU81RNrH7kwZ5Nrr0Jv8PLeKiXOIOo1oyA//0R@ywBjgzhCznqluDEMo7B/FeQtJDXnq4FvUhRVqkzjzbnmCS2JHk@CYbRmFtNZrIi56qyNbemgEsLkZ8s3kdlZdJcYRXXngVoZXMYNa6sAy7vkICsv11zL6XDvltBXRNrPUejp0Gl31@2wAQohfccTbeEURhJJiDhryQmq/5w4CIuUmC1cC0wv4pAz8fMH23Zl56oXnJ@vdBHj99@oLD9C8vvfuAQA24n5k9N4Alo8tNWoJ8ZLi2cJEVPZ@PkszXe2aGT/bf/9YDfa9bY0hvUshgr@aNi5CN0TJ6/17j5Kj4wm@bDfl55MPu5js0XIpZK/Xnjc209shrBt4O@UXINzUgqe/DHAKVwdxed2eYCf6ox2bPzUS5DlfXP4EdeoEOvrxtWNyA8IprOmZW91G5s4gLMpjsJ35Ee6bYfnlsYVGhezahgyi8MZeiuZFc/gFRZ@ssWey3suEoG4k7brK@Zzsvxr@HpmAOadUPn9pH@eMeeBBi@z7fFdMmgeiiH/v0yrzE5kUfmpuHKgaTeAPY0c2e94G9O4upy8xxio@NbvMKsiMf9slnv745O33QfzhBSJsSX9w3knsRurCehNn3KcEofX77M47H/cClPnhfTfgeljn0JTV5dxTr08sb3JcP/7wPIddBuUz0aLH5WFRR4vh@JNclOsSepru7uxlbFFw4ATeCfSL73vIDa4gXwLirvaXmvc7hRfpir5MKj@rj5m5DEKLXlOiuT1PwkSxXM7sGs/DbQz6LS4WLzrNoPeSxd4Sa7Tfv27IsMGPPjWAZj7m98cWHl/tWt7v5wIIMFtL4bYGKb7njPme0h2vutwc9N3Iz3Cnc4zt/ICyJJB23QUt@YUT3Kc2Nxvh371o/jK6ZuG9ejr5slOoPhB3d5y4BieY6es/9nre@81IIOnDbHA6vNkqVuf7G7xijogR2aSmpGtaD5tnozGfGC@OlcWKckTPPj9IH9QF71DQV982uvAC9TDwa6i768HJ7M9pGwfjSRg75/R4DU38Q@ds7A5PCbaNuzkZJH2P7Q2p5OEbZ9ndj1DybiUI7f64LIxLv17y@ON/wp5W8LArfvCQvg6XzSnMB1ouE8e3/bENDCliUGAUQTrIoMQiHU1VaLmuaJJDQMQchgM2geLUPCy6ikJgSiBAZh/X6pN0mxdvJnrVnT0mTyHsy6XYFVb71P5rEvEz3WqC2i7TbLCrv3ytFpRPuEUvhoAx2fJtB6Qpc3@MPIedi6CSkAa/xYHs2UkcUkmD6YvVwSMMe5E9vQo/v1dwoEeUQUXPjueo//t7Li6oDBoMMvJT6oAg8BogCNozG@4Jvzv0wjikWZZEGrNi@2M3pzw5JOvYydyhqqRBd3hyf7@SFsPxIAl5OMXFakkIYFbr6IAPNhNGENL2ICe/LGc@xZoOCkD0KQjL2etkwNWAehi7jhbZZ8QckSRAszJIIvbdCXpAew1SCb0Y/j8C2fhRd8T0wSvKPv4vyH3R66ELYnrHn9egljgSmrM1rbq4bjUDqGZEvLIlyEBWVDAvPCDRyA3OHie8acYeU1yXBE/VZVQ7ZiMrcs8Mzoh8RBU9TsEjneH21ePj6L2/bVrf5jQQmbCtMrAtwvck/6U/sVK6QGYgzRb9a7rage9GrELk4kfNhYeWeF6rnTiVmE1Gxzc01q7IFvOjP/Y6NeZWNl1JDXFexmg6b/jSDV42TFpOmWVRhPxLA/l4/y0gdj5wYqARa4piA4CEOVowQpTghX8kQfUV3iV234E0oxMciZdBc7AKXN97mc3Y54unqddWo1pp8OMWLZqPFWwnrRVjGbn/sjLtmOtNKpzP5yapOQG1RAuCPTZw5R78@vy0aLevr15TeEFmeKg4vDeD0Lt6evjg9Ojs/PH9zBmqcilEWjqMkoIsQgU4Q@xA6h5HPzwVAH4nH0u@HjXnoyBUnv38vF0U7jwEkD1TklNsqN4uSLgepysx8OHSYUSOIijPWYPbbDcGGCyOTJojzHsRZFWb@lhNRVVKkpEFsi2jaai@HF@rah4uAypbEn1085C2gNgPhWAVwLreAEUJuHMT0f0ny08Ozs@9LjlDfkxyApe9xX2J8fPji5TrjJZ4IsNafLwzwWBygHk0g2YX41eeeiWX6mcdE@THLbEJDvB6K2h/1FyEpnZfx0If6GFB9mJPozHzDl@KkJDj/DXLopxAAez2Y0Zc3GQYEiISicjcv38kFGLoxX58qRJYQNm2ul9thwo8hgXA/CeQih@OU000nVh1m/vOvfxOnVJ0M2v@et/vQ/k/R/miigtaPNYSMc9WgWt6@OCUprDJi4AGdLI0JAz0uJF44gqwoAA1ec4UguBB2Md4FHbX9FvQJRgBlYsTCIMX5saSrDrMs3jNNXJchHesbvAzEJmAHiHGGGwXmbyM8NIS4am7Xt7dsE4TUr2cEeS16gDUJQVDT9sB/pGsvbn66dEmj0SByCpta1tx2hCLNIv1Ykz/NBS0CrCSW8DYBHEBZYEBfK0dTi7Rsa4iK80@xFdJ1YHUWdoEAr/IGgGj4Ocz1IcMKEuWqwrI2m2Q8GN7MUhPIC8KIBKgnfnQ8I6QDIUFbk6U13wV5oYcXHryVnNBYNoP8DsF4mWJP3uQ6BDzkvzZ4Tgjt/xDtdsfSv3U3HXvOfedw/XRTvXs2iWMhB2dhhLWoY5CVqFWzWjPtbW1pnsg5KZAWZ8VXIAnzAOaVy7zPUZwePjt68fPJ6dna6RyHVO6CKURpNcod3ai0u/OGcsfnZyp9emyevXp6PFPkslR5112pNhG/K9g9zN6JIs86K96xxsi2/ijhxaZz40AWW9IlwGdiN7rGVdVup@1uo9UJC2vsv246Oi8YJTwth1Yn5QfnCtkQYOZlrPPoCtzjgTNBPUMI78vy6aCXY@PRW7Vl9ti1iWdFkmHOemBtVBsr0mri/FLoYMYe4kT@pWjLwHfBy5XWSgvLgojtXTSXZAVzfbizZQbmaV5yhamP/4KCh0uQlnkgycEvLAzZDVEhigUUggMdwT4w0Sqz/4GqzE@tl6z5L3kF9@7cPlJu/QgiWNF0eALoTGEaf@qQTtbpd0Kcy86N@aNpmM6tWvSbNyaEX62lFodNu1wrlcvFsKQWQwxAjx9j3jgtQny7MGRDngCQXvQ1B1ZViIfNYugUaUMt9prVEseAV9hL3gLCt9Q0bot0ahYfQzipwJeEYdRmajHVMD@0DMOegnyfIy8smpWAxreqTOQJHv4j@6JXLqMMRvECBfhmds7K3Lk6ZybPVJ18WTMHgcOjv7Lqo7//XrC3CZHVaVTer9YeHWi6KptmqfP82lHatF81fuueXp2evlcKz0402d6SnXBLKpgl6@sT0/z06RNEekLaunLdbT9SW0@elCrO9k6pcuAoduXAtn74wbY1tVrVzn74QbXJqaLUa8rZR@U3qdD6AYxb23508MMnqSAVLlpluAx@L5f39g50vCa6Ud6XCp8aANPoTqek3Gg3jFZL77baUuFWKnyZInJz0njN8drPcwLl@u7kJTwaercdn748Ojw7qlQbeqH6/KRSPXvztGDDS33@hl01eHt9dPj85M15pSpQ/vLi7dGb0@PDZ57nxWmvl/aiYbd1cFA2QLatk@2TA6PVbaMEE/j9qdwqN7MsIx8uSuC5z1uTN6beACFeSoXXHEXvaIDwVSq0C211v7pftXzr2prYV/bVq@hk8XtyAh3exPocJdbQGto927YnFntj3UysGyuITuwePBn8WAE0Pas/sQZWaIW2vULn/t/gJHp1EgGpCNCyiZUhVasPz8HJySsg1gfGn@HHsywL5JtY1/Br@Ta/Pl5YliZBut2tb8fV7d/aWFQh9d1um028rCuTitJp4@JfMNNOxxSuJ1fBe7B/Or24eH54fnhxYaLqCoVJo1g@KOsHcDVb5Ub@2C/0Wqg1UKWkqJAWxx3FoU3q8I13EU902na3XLyle6Mpho6SXdL4rK9bjlM6JPnLFrzkzR3HYSl1uRSOIsRSVXZNfVW2O5Nqn1RlDVO6XZh8dq3RULfrWqu1XYfX7R2YGxZ2bmkf7XlXVYsSWZnIUaKQ26n4UW@nDZVfGv5oGn7UiHi0tFu1ATAApPFXgQBg43fv3uHfu/H1WLR4Q3x7N@9cfsELEmwypEQpTAsq35yTrboGCRLTtrbVnfJu/tN8pIFAslLT8EdWpJkRmnYBByAVDOe1bFehB0zi4CY98pnhQxpS25VkuKTmJRt4odRo3YY9qZCmDK7glLIRY@PRaMzm1zMv3aOfP9MY1jrTMTDMV6u7O/Wd3Vp1p7Kzu7NVt7fr9YpdrdhPdp7sWhXbsnfs7Z36rl3Z2dqtbW1t7UJvffeJWZIKPdbHGsJoh8i1nY4lz7/EJIU1JeorsaLb@6MdefsJbJRrTwACVh48WGzgEWxkDFsSHp8TFYyAvgqK0pwp0BbFjG1bKkylHpb1t3YdDCzTRksqKoij1KSCXou2okKxWIQodN6Sa/KJkUpNBloAtRRkRC6kk69R3f4W/uwU9mKltqXUOs2C8DD7iVZoVZ8YKb0pdMU3om7Bx26B@2XVLpCJ93/1C7uT/njJk1a9a0Njcc3dbM3pllob3sfXAf4fWZqmOz/2BgOv@uOnr5DrEEWp1gmxt9EtvukN8duA2/tnJ0JV8nZd1grpx4uPF1Vwmd3d7cLvgPhAZgS98xShz2D1HAWbcoTDxHtFcSsazvMEaLwaQUoydxaC3uJ7l@guK9@EBy1/4v@tC98klAvdRMUGxCS3wvfHpMTjU1cjt7Oqioq9uLHX5nWAhGWjJCSWI@o1SMJz5k3ggu5NmgjAN@8QhlSvaTvEayAxeEImkXPAa4ZRbmLTZ6HKpfC6miMtFzi4JC3AXpJlCb9cFuBTIZYYjxv0xLBF3/wVxAuwjOuqObZ2B6BtdQFG6VhKPsw/MgzId9U5hQr508O4gw9JkzYbExdh0Zl/X5hiKpWySuBIOOxS7Ei/qK52i8mc8y14/Nj9GLeDrqMFzQyf5XLgTKUr1RMgpawZNHXbiUFYJ2uXy163GWi/qDEXPmhaAAy8kXKq3c4tHTZzc6Va5Us71L@F3cpxOyzb3cqoUvrQ/FKhTasygT9QW8Wv/AbKm6lSzZpfyqFDG/CHeeWKJuJmWqbOat0JUK5Uv/mlTbtNS3N8QCyXj2EwIGfa9svlrgbMfehcR3T8x49p2W9NHF/XNYT6WNs/bmfQ6Jab@L6n0sZk/0t7BPh7KjybwMbXQHjAW7UB0AP5HNCxMN9CdCHjBMWbgHhBs1n6sF/6UGo@evSlPdGDbkWof89aGB6Fn6Dwyz6ilj4sOxZXCS/rqvJP3t5PRiklcgW8D5RciZcwhYSlD9ATL2bD9H8A)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11
**68** in Python

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 6 languages have to be tested locally.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 locally.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 using [this interpreter](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip) run using Wine (It probably works on Windows but Windows is not a free software, so it would be forbidden for this challenge (I also don't have it so I can't test it anyway))

### Explanation

We already had two versions of python so I thought, why not add a 3rd.

The first thing Python took issue with was `"1\x2f2"`.   It parses `\x2f2` as one character instead of two separate characters.  In order to remedy this I inserted a new space between `f` and `2`.  Now Python outputs 13 as if it were Ruby.  This meant I wanted to separate it from Ruby and Python 2, making 68 instead of 13.

To do this we rely on python's limited precision, not present in Ruby or Python 2.  In ruby or python2:

```
13<<65>>65
```

Is just 13, but in python it is 0. We use this to short circuit an `or` causing Python to get a 68 instead of a 13.

---

Ok so what did I break?  Surprisingly not much.  When I ran this in TIO the only thing that broke was Brain-Flak Classic.

### Brain-Flak Classic

Brain-Flak Classic had a problem with `<<>>`.  This is a stack switch and caused Classic to get caught in a loop.  We could remedy this by placing parentheses around `65`, this will cause the `<<>>` to become `<<()>>` which is a noop.

### Prelude

Fixing Brain-Flak broke prelude again.  I added a space to counteract the movement caused by fixing Brain-Flak.

Comment: I confirm that it works in surface on windows (no null bytes).

Answer (score 11):

## 69. rk-lang, <s>1750</s> <s>1748</s> <s>1737</s> <s>1734</s> <s>1733</s> <s>1744</s> 1738 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@-----x-.+?
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#x}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{}) ){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#( prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm 
# s 8␛dggi2␛`|$// '' 25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_222999 "69" e rk:start | int os = 69 print: "69"& os rk:end |6#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005308 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1820 bytes)

[rk-lang](//github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang) (Ryan Klingler Language -_-) was a *terrible* language I wrote when I was 13. However, due to the generally awful syntax, it's more or less perfect for this challenge.

## Numbers

This program prints **69** in rk-lang, **68** in Python, **67** in C11, **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

## Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTrLcttIkufGL8ylDLINgCRepEhLAklJtqVZd9strSU/wiQtl8AiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzH/sOfezCrwIZGSuyNmIxaSgAIqKzMrX5WVpQuajn77rYAXOYn866EfZSRjaUb6iXfFEoM8vSb71Evr1Zokcagk6o9dLxySbMSIF8bjjAw8n6WSSzPSJnGOxcAGKZCE0b4AkwZRQnAICS594hE3jsmFT0eGS3yPw6ZRgP0ZS@KEwT0lIWN9ksbM9Qaey@kQNs1YmHpRmBrEcy/JxPN90mc@DFgSdyuAjIzTlU@ClCH1I4nA5cZ3WF28FRnAhGw@XRbThE83IjGf@3zWk4TGMTApFcgpMJ55AUuJlykpYTT1UIYwJGVhn0sqXkg3IjRcnSW58iihwO844bhTlmQwPYPjJSOWMEBJkfgwoQFRJ4mXgQhQkAfkhNGEnCWMaUAFFMBSl8bAxy2SQCxCChlOxOCKajaVw@MjBRQmRhg0zqRCUjv7158kSowWKZ478NeSZUc6/OU5uSl2sQ1cADJQapyoVCOtbyQ1u10Gf1P7whwmMwmwSiAVn5hRnJmAmSYZsLds6VdVI/ZXyJLmHU2sGJGA6oMuyIuQvK3webnjJGHAxVKk9BKm7EfhEKQJU03GIUojJA0LFOBGYT@tEHYFMotCoaFowuV7NvJAZSkqhF6AeKiLkhcOwMUJLgCWl8tzTjeN/DGHg5FphuYHMoGhiPHFgLwlA@r5OAT6EZXgOmHp2M9wzDjso94DL2R9g8zZcKM@AgXRFZCjgJR/AJ8JVjyNMwXAoIaITxW7/vGXv/aHQ8Bz4LpR0s@N9S3pR@44AIYpZ5aCIaK5RiH1OVsAV0HqYjgQuKK@16cZkg@vcxKcCU51Eo39PomAYDLxwLFG9AqccTBgbsaEiUfjDHiskIBeivjgCbuFiQf0AhTLCXDafNo62X8GWnKZMBg9GGeDbaLHh0RJzY/q3q6696jLgDfN0EpF0xw6YG1GiX@CN@Uhw3l7sNQnWs@ZF6EX@fFoDDEDesI0hmiSoDBdCtNJMahkEPMq5IILmkciMHTuohOmJIxcgF/PJ8ZtRNgAjtfRb3MMS53O4W6bGOuvWBhYJxhZlq4FCT@aAGHOGwZOsOkQidMhBVJZPqEDMSFBkX@5PbXLECwdsV0wsq1feKAdtAMINbkyVuYI4LWqgAFsQnsrThHQa8DiihC91CTxBqDkAOw2uSYuQ2cAr2AiziGRMTeM1AM7igbE0qv1@neUnyXmgf7BpPoX80Ed4@TvqPmADNiE@DQcjukQDDkKYQh1XRZnuQfBTNIMfORuGOQf9TymG@lIKu7fpc1jWx7tV2hg9BHayyM0RbMHQQUgat0HLyc0GXJPJH0vAX/xr@9SB4CrO8TlTwhyi4FP8j0szBcmMDI2Ze44A3cDQ56MPHcEtovchcJhRXS8Sx4@rVKHkKMPFqSRGbv9uCoZ5uITsnEvCh01uo4Hoj6iat/6wJW/@uFhzDQNNiCOFixChFr5apjUANvLhQar@SlmEhD@5ks396xFerGQJwj4J1yYEvbrGBQG9uwNQwSh4WLZX4mMXhoqsFR4qQdSxwUcbf3sxTGuB@@YyGFA7mItWw3mEWQ0MDxfoLFjrgSJuaOI6CFRch5Uma@nn4EtM01c3tBXkghZM0BOKsqLd80RfRZ52d0FlbTX4ThJpUI6styrwBrmp2BC4dj34WUcchdTmXYDtuayNDXAYUC2BmYjwJ1cZtrsNmA2SqIJYTPNUTaR@4MKeTa@8Kb/DzXiIl/iDrNaUQP/9Hv0sAY4V4Qs56JbgxDCOwP2XkLSQ156uBYNIEVaps48255iktiV5Pg6G0Vh7XY0kZc9VZGtvTUDWFyM@HrzOiqvouIDXnnhZYRaMoN569wy7PotFJDtr48ceOmI326BrrG13sNHp8HFgN82AIRoBXeMjXcEURgJ4iAhL6Tma/4wIGJu4uB2YLpF/ikDOx8yfadmXnihecEG90EePX36gsMMLi68@4BADLifmT83gCXji01SgnxktLZwkVtyPhsnma/3zQyf7L//rQ/yXtfGiF6nkMFeLhrnIZugZvTBvcrJh@ILv21W5OexD7ub7@BwKWat1F80NuPaJa8ZWDvkFyHf1ACnvg8@BCID3143Z/AEf9xn8@dmpFyGt9c/MTr0Ah1suWFYXIHwims6Zlb3YbmziAs0mOwnfkT7pth@eWypUSF7NqXDKLw2V6K5kVz8Dlbn6yxZ7rey0Tgbiztusr6nOy/Gv4dcMIe06gdP7cP8cQ88MNG4z3aF2yQQXfQjn16aF9g8H0Bz81TFZBJvCDu6@fM@sHenMXWZOUnxsdFsXkF25MM@@fSXN6cnD9oPRwhpU@KL@0Z0L0IX1pMw@z4mmKXPb3/E8LgduNQH66sJ28Myh74iJu@OYH16cY378tEftyGkOiyXiR4tNx/LKkoc3z/IdYkOsafl7uxsHi0KLhyBG8E@kX1v@YE1xAtg3tX@SvNe4/AifbnXSYVFDXBztyEI0StKdNenKdhIlouZXYFa@O0hm8WlwkXjWbYestg7TM33m/dtWZYjY8@NYBmPub7xxYeX@1a3u/nAEg0W0vhtORTfcsN9zmgf19xvD1pu5Ga4U7jHdn5HWBJJOm6DVuzCiO4TmhtN8O/etX4UXTFx37wcfdnI1e8IO7rPTQISzfXhffd71vrOSyHowG1zOLzcyFXm@hu/Y4yKEtilpaRqWA@qZ6MxnxovjJfGsXFKTj0/Sh@UB@xR01TcN5vyEvQi8Wiou2jDq@3NwzYyxpc2csDv9yiY@sPIb2wPTQq3jbI5HScDjO0PieXhGGXb341Ri2wmCu38eR/HySX83ukUKflrXnlclALSSl4whW9ekhfI0kUNugArScJ4YWC@1SEFLFeMAwg0WZQYhMOpKi2XNU0Sg9BkhyGAzaF4HRBLMaLEmBKIHRmH9Qak0yHFm@mutWvPSIvIuzLp9QRWXhQ4nMa8gPdaDO0Uaa9VVN6/V4pKN9wllsJBGewFN4PSW3ADjz8En8upk5AGvPqD7flMHVFiAsfGuuKIhn3IrN6EHt/FuVEiCiWiGsez2L//rZ@XW4cMJhl4KfVBEHhAEAVsFE32BN2c@kEcUyzXIg5Yy32xz9OfHZB04mXuSFRZIe68OTrbzktk@WEFvJxgSrXChVAqdA2AB5oJpQlu@hETdpkTXoyaTwqC@TgIycTrZ6PUAA8NXcZLcPOyEHCSIFiYJRHadYW8IH2GSQbfpn4eg279KLrku2Pk5O9/E4VB6PTQhLA9J88r1SsUCTizzatxrhuNges5ki8siXIQFYUMS9IYJHINXsXEd424I8orlmCJ@rxeh2REze7ZwSnRD4mC5yxYvnO8gVo8eP3ntx2r1/pGAhM2HCZWDLjc5B/1J3YqV8gcxJmhXa12W9C97FWIXJzK@bSwps9L2AujEt5EVGxzdc3rbwE/DuB2xya8/saLrCGuuFhnD1PwD3jVOGrhNK2iCjuVAHb@@mlG6ngYxUAk0BIHCASPd7CWhEOKU/KVjNBWdJfYdQvehEB8LF8GreX@cHVLbj5nF2OeyF5VjWqtxadTPG8127yVsH6EBe7Ox@6kZ6ZzqXS70x@t6hTEFiUA/thEzzn85flN0WhbX7@m9JrI8kxxeNEA3bt4c/Li5PD07ODszSmIcSZmWTiKkoAuQwQaQexDUB1FPj8xAHkkHku/HzYWoSMXnPz@vVwU7TwGkDxQkROuq1wtSroapCpz9eHUwaPGEBXnpEHtNxuCDWdGJi1g5z2wc5uZxVuORFVJkZImsS2iabd7ObwQ1x5cBES2wv784iFvCbUZCOcqgHO@BYxgcuMkZv8kzk8OTk@/zzlCfY9zAJa@R32F8NHBi5frhFdoIsBaf74wwGN5tHo4hTQY4teAWyYW8OcWE@UHMHOHhng9ElVB6i9DUroo8KENDTCg@uCTaMx8K5iiUxL0f4Mc@CkEwH4fPPriOsOAAJFQ1PQWhT25AFM3FutThcgSwqat9UI8OPwEUgv3kxhc5HAcc7rpLKvLzH/85a/i/KqbQfvf8/YA2v8p2h9NFND6gYfgcSEaFMvbFyckhVVGTDyg05U5YaDHhcQLx5AvBSDBKy4QBBfMLue7xKN23oI8QQkgTIxYGKQ4PZb01FGWxbumiesyJGoDgxeI2BT0ADHOcKPA/HWMx4kQV81GvbFlm8CkfjVHyKvUQ6xWCISatgv2I115cevThUuazSaRU9juslbDEYI0i/RjTf60YLQIsJJYwjsExsCQ5Qjoa@fD1CIt2xoORf9TbIX0HFidhV4gwKu8ASAafg5zeciwgkS5qLDgzaYZD4bX89QE8oIwIgHKiR8qzxHpgEjg1mRpzXaBX@jhJQnvVk5orKpBfodgvICxK28yHQIW8l8bLCeE9n@Idqdr6d96mw5EF7ZzsH7uqd49tcS5kP3TMMIq1RHwStSqWa2ZdkNb8RM5RwXcold8BZTgB@BXLvM@R3F68OzwxU/HJ6dr53YcUrkLphCl3Sx3daPS6S0ayh2bn4v06ZF5@urp0VyQq1zlXXe52oT8LmP3EHsnyj/rpHjHGiHb@r2Il9vRjRNZblZXAJ@JfeoaVVW7mXV6zXY3LKyR/7rpUL1glPAcHVrdlB@pK2RDgFkUuM6iSzCPB04L9QwhvC@r54ZePhoP5apts8@uTDxFkgxz3gNro9q8xa0mTjaFDObkIU7kX4q2DHSXtFxpreiwyojY@EULTm6NXJ/ufJkBP82LseD6@M8peOwEaZkHnOz/zMKQXRMVolhAITjQMewQE60y/@@oyuI8e0Wb/5LXdu/69qFy40cQwYqmwxNAZwZu/KlLull30A3Rl51r80@mYTo3atFvXZsQfrW2Why17HKtVC4Xw5JaDDEAPX6MeeOsCPHt3JANeQpAetHXHFhVIR62iqFTpE212G9VS3wEvMJe8gYGfEtN46ZIZ2bxMYSTCnxJGEZtphZTDfNDyzDsGfD3OfLColkJaHyjykSe4r8FIPmiVy4jD0bxHBn4ZnZPy9y4uqcmz1SdfFkzh4HDo79y20Z/@61gNwiR1VlU3qvWHu1ruiqbZqn7/MpROnRQNX7tnVyenLxXCs@ONdnekp1wSyqYJevrE9P89OkTRHpCOrpy1es8UttPnpQqTmO7VNl3FLuyb1s//GDbmlqtaqc//KDa5ERR6jXl9KPyq1Ro/wDKrTUe7f/wSSpIhfN2GS6D38vl3d19Ha@pbpT3pMKnJsA0e7MZKTc7TaPd1nvtjlS4kQrTGQ5uTZuv@bjO8xxBub4zfQmPpt7rxCcvDw9ODyvVpl6oPj@uVE/fPC3Y8FJfvGFXDd5eHx48P35zVqmKIX9@8fbwzcnRwTPP8@K030/70ajX3t8vG8Db1nHjeN9o94CR6Y/ldrmVZRn5cF4Co33enr4x9SbQfykVXnNovasB7Fep0Cl01L3qXtXyrStral/al6@i4@Xv8TF0eFPrc5RYI2tk923bnlrsjXU9ta6tIDq2@/Bk8GMF0PSswdQaWqEV2vYtPPf/BsfRq@MIUEUwLJtaGWK1BvAcHh@/AmQDIPwZfjzLsoC/qXUFv5Zv8@vjuWVpEmTavXojrjZ@7WA9hdR3eh029bKeTCpKt6P0nIKZdrumMDq5CnaD3bPZ@fnzg7OD83MT1VYoTJvF8n5Z34er1S4388deod9GoYEkJUWFhDjuKg5tUYdvuYt4ytOxe@XiDd0dzzBolOySxv29bjlO6YDkL1vwkje3HYel1OVcOIpgS1XZFfVV2e5OqwNSlTVM5nbA7exas6k26lq73ajDa2MbvMLCzi3to73oqmpRIitTOUoUcjMTP@rNrKnyS8MfTcOPGhGPtnajNgEGgDT@KgYA2OTdu3f4925yNREt3hDf3i06V1/wgtSajChRCrOCyrflZKuuQWrEtK2Gul3eyX9ajzRgSFZqGv7IijRXQssu4ASkguG8lu0q9IBKHNyeRz4zfEhAajuSDJfUumBDL5Sa7ZuwLxXSlMEVnFA2ZmwyHk/Y4nrmpbv082cawypnOgYG@Gp1Z7u@vVOrble2d7a36najXq/Y1Yr9ZPvJjlWxLXvbbmzXd@zK9tZObWtrawd66ztPzJJU6LMBVg/G20SubXctefElJimsJtFAiRXd3htvy40nsEWuPQEIWHPwsLGJx7KRMWpLeKROVFACmioISnNmgFuUMRq2VJhJfSz1b@04GFJmzbZUVHCMUpMKei3aigrFYhHiz1lbrsnHRiq1GEgBxFKQcXAhnX6N6va38CensBsrtS2l1m0VhIXZT7RCu/rESOl1oSe@EXULPvYK3C6rdoFMvf@r38FkxYxum9aGxvJa2Niaxa20NrxPrgL8x7KUbP@pPxx61T99@goZDlEUUq0TYjfQJr7pTfHbhNv7Z8dCTnKjLmuF9OP5x/Mq2MvODpEbOzJhJLnchd1OgikXVgVTUX3a5d2PCbwDAP6D79dG4Tcg9UAGBb2LVGLAYJUdB5tyiYPEe0Vxyxou8glovBpD6rIwLYK25XsXaFy3vgl7W/3E/98XvknIFxqVig2IYG6F76NJiUeznkZu5tUXFXuxAKAt6gUJy8ZJSCxH1HUQhecsmkAFnYG0EIBv8iFoqV7LdojXRGTwhIwjp4DXfES5hU2fhSrnwutpjrRaCOGctGH0Ci8r48tlAT4TbIn5uEFfTFv0LV6BvQDLva6aj9buAHSsHsAoXUvJp/l7pgF5sbrAUCF/eBp3xkNypc3nxFlYdubfl6qYSaWsEjgSTrsUO9LPqqvdYNLnfAseP3Y/xp2g52hBK8NnuRw4M@lS9QRIKWsFLd12YmDWyTrlstdrBdrPasyZD1oWAANtxJxqNwtNh61cXalW@dIJ9W9hr3LUCct2rzKulD60vlRoy6pM4Q/EVvErv4Lw5qJUs9aXcujQJvxh/nlLEnErLVPndn0KhlyqfutLh/Zalub4MLBcPoLJAJ9pxy@XexoQ96FzfaDjP35My3576vi6riHUx9reUSeDRq/cwvddlTane186Yxi/q8KzBWR8DZiHcbd1APiAPwdkLNS3ZF3wOEX2psBe0GqVPuyVPpRajx596Uz1oFcR4t@1lopH5qfI/KqNqKUPq4bFRcLLv6r8o7f7o1FKiVwB6wMhV@KVkYLD0gfoiZfeMPufMNJd6o7Y/wI)

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident tested to output 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ was tested to output 48 by [WheatWizard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37900058#37900058).
- Moorhens 2.0 was tested to output 60 [by WheatWizard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37900301#37900301).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 using [this interpreter.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip)

## Explanation

I appended this line: `# p rk:start | int y = 69 print: y & s rk:end | 6#`

rk-lang ignores everything before `rk:start` and everything after `rk:end`. It is completely space-delimited. It ignores anything it doesn't care about.

### rk-lang

I started out with this code to print 69:

```
rk:start int y = 69 print: y rk:end
```

### ALGOL-68

To make this work with ALGOL-68, I had to add ALGOL-68 comments around it. So it looked like this:

```
# rk:start int y = 69 print: y rk:end #
```

### Wise

To make it work in Wise: Wise recognizes `~-!|^&[]?:`. My code uses `:`. A `|` or `&` before any other characters Wise cares about will cancel that out.

```
# rk:start | int y = 69 print: y | rk:end | #
```

### SMBF

To make it work in SMBF: SMBF recognizes `><+-.,[]` and, based on the rest of the code, prints the second-to-last character in the file. Therefore, the second-to-last character in the file must be `6` so that it prints properly:

```
# rk:start | int y = 69 print: y | rk:end | 6#
```

### Alphuck

To make it work in Alphuck: Alphuck recognizes `aceijojps`. `p` and `s` are jumps. Since there is an `s` in `rk:start`, I had to add a `p` before that to get the jump to cancel out. Since there was a `p` in `print:`, I had to add an `s` after it to cancel that out. Since `rk-lang` conveniently ignores these if put in the "wrong" syntax, I can just stick them pretty much anywhere.

```
# p rk:start | int y = 69 print: y | s rk:end | 6#
```

### Incident

To make it work in Incident, I had to make sure no extra characters were tokenized/detokenized. This was pretty simple - I just had to swap one of the `|`'s to an `&`. So the code looks like this:

```
# p rk:start | int y = 69 print: y & s rk:end | 6#
```

On top of that, I added one character earlier on in the line. It looked like this:

```
# sss8ggi2|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#
```

I simply added a space before the `2` near the end to prevent Incident from tokenizing it:

```
# sss8ggi2|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_ 2229996#
```

## Fixing

It broke because we realized the interpreter automatically prints a space after it prints an integer. This was what the rk code needed to look like:

```
rk:start print: "69" rk:end
```

Adding that to the code messed up Alphuck and Incident. So I added random stuff here and there to balance Alphuck jumps and Incident tokens out:

```
"69" e rk:start | int os = 69 print: "69"& os rk:end |6#
```

The extra `"69"` at the start detokenized `"6`. The `e` detokenized `e<space>`. The `os` was necessary for Alphuck jumps. Switching `"69" &` to `"69"&` detokenized `9"`.

## Golfing

Saved two bytes - changed my code to `#p rk:start | int y = 69 print: y & s rk:end |6#` by removing two spaces. I forgot that the languages who required these characters are not space-delimited, as rk-lang is.

Saved 11 bytes thanks to SnoringFrog:

> So I took advantage of the `s`'s we could add to RK to cut out some alphuck filler. Then I found out that `os` could replace the `ax` that Moorhens was using. I moved the detokenization of `<space>2` to earlier in the line so that it also helps with Prelude padding (and then removed a space from several lines up to also then detokenize `'<space>`).

Knocked off three bytes thanks to a suggestion by Chance to remove `# #`.

Saved a byte thanks to WheatWizard pointing out an unnecessary space.

Comment: `# #` could also be dropped. this just drops out of Algol's comment, then immediately initiates another one. It could instead just be one large comment. Well done!

Comment: Does the space between `|` and `6` need to be there?  I can't see why it might and removing it doesn't break anything on TIO.

Answer (score 11):

## 87. Alice, 2448 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#~
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO/"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<\>@*99[?]*]*.*|!)'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
' (<><       (          )> ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};

" }"';           (( ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main ( ␉){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxx"78"\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003717 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2533 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTtdd9pIls/R2X8wL2VBRxKgLzA2RoDtTuzZ9HTa3thJ5jQQR4gCFOuDSMLgEHL2dffsw7zPyz7O/5jX/RXzR3rvrZIAG2ynz@6es2CkUtWtW/er7r1VJffsePTbbzn8kPPQux16YUISGiekH7k3NNLIj7fkyHbjarkiCAwqCvsTxw2GJBlR4gbjSUIGrkdjwbET0iLjFIuGBZIjEbX7HEwYhBHBLsS/9ohLnPGY9Dx7pDnEcwH21KgBfBz6CJPQaBxRuMYkoLRP4jF13IHrsLEInSU0iN0wiDXiOtdk6noe6VMPOqwIcEqAjEzitSo@nCb0Q4HAxxnfI3f5lKcAE9CMZTq2I8ZySMaM/4zzaWSPx0CkkCMXQHji@jQmbiLFhNqxi3KELjEN@kxa46WEQ2IH61ySG9cmNtA7iRjumEYJsKcxvGREIwoobRx8GNk@kaeRm4AIUJjH5JzaEbmMKFVgFFACjR17DHTcGRIGC3GEBBnRmLIaDenk7FQCpfEemj1OhFxUufyXnwSbaE2Sv7Lg1xRFSzj55SWZ5ztYBioAGSh2HMm2QprfSKx3OhR@M7OnD6OFAFgFkIpH9HCc6LY6BgLVBAjUbSxiSb0pa2NvbWDSuKeLNVPiUH3QBnkVkHclxpkziSIKdKyEal8D014YDEGewGw0CVAeAdkzQAVOGPTjEqE3ILUw4DoKp0zClyMXlBajSuweCMh2UPZ8GjCBwkQA20slmo0bh96EwUHPOEEDBKlAV8T4akDekYHtetgF2hEVpzqi8cRLsM8k6KPmfTegfY1kZDhhH4H88AaGswEpq4CZ46/NN0YUAIMiQsYqNv3jL3/tD4eA59hxwqifmus70g@diQ8E24xYG0wRDTYMbI@RBXAlHJ13hwFubM/t2wkOH9ymQzAi2KjTcOL1SQgDRlMXptbIvoHpOBhQJ6HcyMNJAjSWiG9fcy/hcssFxn27B4plA7CxGdsqOXoBWnIoNxnVnySDGlHHJ0SK9Q/yYV0@3OlQoE3RlEJe14cW2JtWYFXwJD1mOO@OV/pE67l0Q5xH3ng0Aa8BLUE8Bn8SoTAdG9iJ0a0k4PlKpMcEzXwRmDqbpFMqRZT0YGZnjDEb4TaA/VWcuSmGlU4zuLsmRvtrFgbWCUaWxBtuwgunMDCjDd0n2HSAg9tDG4ZKUoaOOUN8RFZzl7XrACwdsfUoqak9F7SDdgDOJlXGGo8AXilzGMDGtbc2KXz7FrA43EmvNEncASjZB7uNbolDcTLArKDc0@EgE2YYsQt2FA6IoZar1SeUn0T6sforeI8v@qM6RubvqfmYDOiUeHYwnNhDMOQwgC6249Bxks4g4CROYI7cd4SsUk29uhaPhPzR/bGZd0v9/doY6H249lIfbaPZg6B8ELXqwSwndjRkM5H03Qjmi3d7f3QAuLk3uPgRQe4Q8FF8gIQsNIGR0Rl1JglMNzDk6ch1RmC7SF3AJyz3jveHh6r10cHlqIPl0EiM2XpeFjR9WYVkPIhCRY1u4gGvj6hadyqY8tcrHsdsx/4WxOGSRPBQa7Wabmtge6nQIJ5fYC4B7i8L3mxmLROMpTxBwD9hYIro5wkoDOzZHQYIYgfLwL/mGd04kCBUuLELUscQjrZ@@eoM48F7yrMYkDuPZevOPIScBrqnIRobMiUI1BmFRA2IlNIgiyyifgKy9DhyWEFdSyNERQM5ySgv1pQh@sSzs/sBlbQ24diQUom0RbFbghjmxWBCwcTz4GESsCkmU2UOtubQONZgwoBsNcxHgDqxSJXFXcBkFIVTQheKJW0b7ncq5MWk587@H2rEQbr4FbhaUwOr@h49bABmihDFVHQbEEx2L0If/Tx5zzhGen@MIDYMIB4I49tkBJ5OdYhoN8MxBZLueBIJ6IT0XFYsltJJkvYpdAN5Lu3s7Eh1qSWVoHQIpQaWDrFUhNIhK6mshHAalliPEitha5v1wLqutGhnmGdKF1U7w7z1izuW7Xa9XumW7LaZ3st4VyCYQOwAaBVvgEdSmk0sKorYmgKjWm8gcPYvQTk/Q8pHfnYxEg8gQVwtHYTlYB1B5MKo3PWl4qqlzLPVG90H8Wnj2@1ZhLiOinWABO46RBtdla4MzazeQQErns2eAzcescsd0A2yNltY79jvDdhlC0A9TQMgp8BVEsqFuTLMRMIQLH/KwPwwCDkpIC83sPU37KZB9NhGz10nfYeYHoU5P6R6zw2w/ASYelBjkINez30IFOSCpGf3LWDRpLdNbJCejTbiOLkj@GQSJR7tp/f/@tc@KGBTPSP7NoaE/npZuAK5oarUwYPaSrviA7ts1@yniQfLvSdwODYm8ba3LGzHVSdvKJg/aDZgqzyg1APeMMMBV7dp3zA1vEmfZvftSJkM76YDvHfg@kxzcMfchnmeB7rfS2Z4f1z0RF5o93W@EHXpSpVc6HRmD8PgVl@LalrU@w4as3yDrFaeyWiSTPgVF5tPKc0d4@@xyZhCGlW7Z1I9jO2e@4AEkYi9h4yWzwV00@rAs6958QqL21nlzETuEFa22f0hMMj2ICEf2w7Vp@z2oP8IJvGYKZOVHsEXefz6EIgbOBBZg1XhIUBg02OX32NyzBAcmAdIKm72qGsicu8J1bN7txjKRr/ffnDAYbFIVPAdTadYNCpEDVdrsdW20nj8cH/HSfsfHGzvzXegGAInhGUzfSoeQVBxfdtTy/214oP@NQv9q9I292Pf2JAUeHYMBpKkYqY3oBZ2ecxoMU44E8@OVqVHTHZFTrbkfmjVtuozdp3Qc1PLzB62DBBgmnc/JVqhwR1Fdll1xafUZb6ErAcD77dH/WboJLhYesB0vsMj8XUKrgTXbEELHxKXE07x9@CEHYU3lF@3h6AvW6n6Do@jeswYINfe7N53nrJQ3Adil@2e8HorVYnjba2vk9dhGMFCNSZlzXhUPVvNOHa9MCYX7PqYLGCJHsf8ut2A18Xm2oHqjPi0Wpa3d9tKFIto5JhdH1Cu7Q1Db6821G24PGgBk2iAjj29f69TWzol03zSKS3TlzAw0/uD3vwa/p4yDtwAAfftYh6zLG43lAc9WJrxP8wgpPm44bWduVOjtrSsKKaPmlSdHEfOaGrfPgr1VOR4SMxZ5KjjZj1LhP9nw@w@Pkz/@7zUBtr9x9HeUe@1R8FNs@uGUknZMH9nD9Mwvt9nDbwJndCtPuSs94mC4Xx3UvwoUUbKRp18ufYexfldZGMUx6dHfY7tuTDPn8ph2Ar4DTvmWO47xqX0fAbq3CjdjY@XR165V4ETUbYLme2rkBzujU58COZJGGmEwcmyXSwqisA7YXAYBgCWQbFDB9z35ecZMYEonTBYWLu32yQ/n9WNurkgTSLWRdLtcqxsB/JkNmanBW9413be7jbzkqpKeakT1IkhMVDqwVzdCmrfgRu47MbpXLFOAttnW81Yzji1@H42hFA8xBjZQR@WL28Dl20ZOWHEd2X51v8lrg3//rd@erYzpMCk78agmGGA55GhT0fh9JCPm45@PB7beDaEOCBj9vimkvrimMRTN3FG/EgHIvzb08tauh@fno/CwzmuW9ao4EqFpgHQYCdcaZyafki5GaYDL3tlTEHaNPEDMnX7ySjWIB4GDmX7/dkeNFASIViQRCGacYm8In2K6TvbE/s0Ad16YXjNtuKQkr//jZ9CQKOLJoTlbHh2LLY2IgEzNtnWv@OEE6A6Q/KFRmEKIqOQIfmbgERuYRJRXq8QZ2Sz4xGwRDU7HMBh@AHBi@MLop4QCY918azAcgdy/vjNH9@1jW7zG/F1WM7ruD3J5Cb@oO6bsVgiGYi1QLtabzagedUqETE/E1O28ACRnZctjYrPJiJjmakr2@z32dkjszs6ZZv97EQnwNwWD/WCGOYHPCoMNZ80zbw88VzfTYh6kZAqnn1TEAmU@GklwdNk3LjGLvkZ@UpGaCuqQ8yqAU9cIB6elfjNH7Odlcr6Dpj@kvYmbLV4U9bKlSZjJ3/VbLRYKaL9EE/T2h86064eZ1LpdGY/GOUZiC2MAPy5jjPn5JeX87zWMr5@jSE8iuJCstgOJU7v/Pz81fnJxeXx5dsLEOOCc5k7DSPfXrkINIKxB3nLKPTY8STII3Jp/LTbeMb8hvAsBZRlkrdJA6IFAQ/1bOlYUrGKqpjnRd7GPMmy7V5j6j4GLkldHTln2k4VK8Xrbq6UGQAKD@bkBPxqRjwYznyLu2LsiKQJDKnAEANfErx82sbY3VYGzwV@iM8g9JSNdSjG6gpqOxDyyoFTujkMJ3IrE4v/JcrHEEeephyhnqIcgIWnRl8b@PT41c9v35xsjr02bAqzAbK0kLU3Qk5mkG@CHxwwC8dTx8xuwvTUOHMM4PdH/CjD9lauLV6eSqAlDdAxezC3cVKwPZsYJzdBP6KRYy8GR9rvg2fo3SboWMCj8oOI5WmEmAMBaMs4VyKigLBxc/P0EBzHFNYDzkfeOc/gGOZ42wF8h@r/@Mtf@aF7J4Hyv6XlAZT/g5c/6CigzVNaTuNSNCiWd6/OSQzRijPu27M1njBgYEByA8jqXB8keMMEguCc2BW/Kzxy@x3IE5QAwkTPh86OjUejrjxKknFd1zG@w/JqoLFtXDoDPYCv1GBBon@e4DsQ4J/1vererqkDkepNhpAdrQ1xa5EjVJQ6mJBw446bH3sOaTQaRIwd26PNPYsLUs/bHyrixyWheYAVeCrQJtAHuqx6QFsr7Sbn7aKpYFechZIpka4FUZ7rBQKFzAoAomB1kMpDhEgUpqLCUzo6S5hTvc1SHMgvgpD4KCf2JkyGSAVEHLciChu2u9pCxKOTNWvW1tUgvkewCwSri9tMh4CF/OcWywmg/O@83O4Y6rfutrc4lrZzvPmyhnz/VQvkhRxdBCFuKZ8CrUQu6@WKbu4pa/NETFEBtTgrvgJKmAcwrxzqfgrH8fGLk1c/nZ1fbLxswCCl@2ASkVqNYkfVSu3usiDds/lMpD@e6hevfzzNBLlOVdp0n6ptyO8T9sBg7/lm7eZQrGFjINP4XsTsZFE9ZYuXLYwsW/U1wBd8Z2ljVFmZL9rdRqsT5DaG/7rtTaCcVsCXf6DUidl7QBLZ4mBeZVvQl@E1mMcjrzioCUK4X9Zfdsg2sPFNgnJL79MbHY@@BW21tS3m5cYdahX@OgaXQTY8@Im0Jg@LxxZZjeUIG9uE64Tw3ZpwScmdnkthI89nfGXH3mayA0jqI9fh0DFzrnz9x169gRXAq2S1aICFCC6O2drolq0DYJovt936LtuRtaPblINlywX1XfUyowcn/ep8GZxQGCWw/IhHntuz7GZ7Rpanr48dPWvx2HMTGc98Zxqur4AbWUEGzIZH8ci4cdBNz6dJdoxcZCfR5xOQ13k4Jqs17Uuald7Asoa8nABysABKfpr4ADdgtzcUPTwlv4QqdAY5ShkRbRhFTnnQ/H4VRtdGdNZ3hxAlZKUEDuUH01ydYdtKEdaiEvhQLqo/4n7iumB@17n7msTstq25QZ/OZGkqKfUuSgfqpen7G0kRN2yAHf6nbwL0778FkM19O0kn4fIEfX3iZAkLDJ6ewUEQwXcz8a0LWCi4YNNHf6JBACYjA9k@GAixJ8BnpJSyV4RLy9e51vzCP6dHevejxIk090KIhXndYksSawEB4WOHdJLOoBNgVLBu9T/omm7N5bzXvNUhkCstOT9qmsVKoVjMBwU5H2Aoe/4cVzKLPETKK03UxBkAqXlPsUCeEFmb@cDK2w0532@WC6wHPBaLyhw6fIt1bZ63F3r@OQSmEtRE3DrkfKygOgxNMxdAH2oor5d8ezyXRSLO8K04HD7vFotIg5a/QgK@6Z2LInNTnQudrZ2sNEHSh35mxneM4bffcuYe5OoLOSwelis7RyoR9ULn5Y0lte1BWfvcPb8@P/@z0pGl3Isz0dwVrYIu5PSC8XVf1z9@/Ag5A1HaqtRty639/YJV2qsVSkclUypZOeKZhmkqcrmsdHaDC/LMevbsmWyeS1K1Il18wFc5Dnfgy/7gs3zE6w6rSasZyOZnRyHy55mQaz0DO6ns7Rw9@yjkvgm5q1YRPhq7Fov1@pGqqjP4acVDIfexAUCQCuVare5iUWy0Gw2t1Zq11G6rLeTmQm62EHJlEcVQEHLNWeMNw9J@maIrfv4ZLg212x6f/3xyfHFSKjfUXPn0@EWpfPH2x5wJT9XVIzZW8PHNyfHLs7eXpTLv9cdX707enkO967rjuN@P@@Go2zo6KmpA6JHW6gIxsx@KrWIzSRLy61VBs6Pds72zIyH3sjV7q6sNoOJnIfeGdVA7CnT5KuTaubZ8WD4sG55xY5jX5vXr8Gz1d3ami/s1MQyPoN2dGZ/CyBgZI7NvmubMoG@NW@N2ZvjhmdmHIoWv4UPRNQYzY2gERmCad/A9/Oefha/PQkAVQrdkZiSI1RjAfXh29hqQDWDgT/B1DQPpnBk38Gd4Jvt8uDIUQ4DlYbe6Ny7vfW4zR1M96LbpzE26IilJnbbUtXJ63Ono3LLFMhgnNi8WV1cvjy@Pr650XC/NGvniUVE9gk@zVWykt8Ncv4WS0xqCJE/fv3@Pv/fTmykvsQKve79sXH9gBfjcPND3bkGWtcLmt2YeaEUoFI/a1e58oRD4PutIlsQZkmUKAVQWzc6sPCBlkcWlA/AKZgVyf3mvqrRae1V43qspqmxg667ywWw00qayEkaiNBPDSCLzBf/K80VDZh8Fv4qClem1pcjQrFThaTaXZw25IWMdVGGv@aKFRQY3h1JbVrrKYsHr4CorDY6zpQDLmPn/H/2FMSxTiZRb5DASBGS3qsC6giq7e3KteJB@mzvAjCxWpArwKEq21G4fFSqF/d32YbfQLciNTuuocHDAn7TC1x1FygmZ2TTNHMpNyGnWG9EsixKakYX7aKFHNQ8y/MqBIMJHkIjcaDXStbq82itQWkSZk1RKRFnMQatpEwQEOd3r6nRmhsHArV4zP8/ZC0sQRLIQl8B8Mxwwy5LFNkDFuZi3o7bZFRdift5bYMQsmAqLddVdyyrs8vJ@zbKgoZC2GNCSFqGBxrbDZgq4aDQFCWSkCM0eHbqBAEG9B2Kekn0DkjbPsyMSDgY7vB6yE1jWUYjO1PNwfYzJ@TSMvP4UEsYdIRdT@PjnNp1QOp1MpnT5eeHGdfvTJ0g6xxhBIKcwBA3jf7l8UKvWDirlWql2UNutmnvVasksl8z92v6BUYIQUjP3atUDs1TbPajs7u4eQGv1YF/I0aDvDnQdvLQpioQVIHPFF4sa@ApWqI1aRMj16QC3RJ95cl95lusvKyY1IlZqHaNjiAK@dQdSfqbM0dHIJIYcMxwQ2ShNYG5VDyc1cW9frBfgLh6KFSh6MjEkUJ4odURRaR90D8X9KqCqQ1RTpefmIRH3D8S6uL8PlYq1AOoyrpd0E3A/mkbgp6oCtvMILYv7MNklC8As3uWf1vpE1/U4sSNczTBwSPb3DkSsBpBGq9or1EumWjriyMieKeQWQh9fY9g9sDC@wVRvtIS8hDxLFSGnVsLdMJfP5yEqXrbEinimNfQ01LV0Fuo6GPowzGhZ5GwJEcU91D7@Tw73VrWqYmFlLDShXrBgfuTE3O2MfzDsdDjKxrccO6Im53Pc2kpf162/Bnpku37BXs1qw6z59ovrzWsVtcXyRMhXF2SBzOTir2HV/Bb8ZOXqY6myK1U6zRynwdxXcq3yvhbbt7kuryPy7r5C4ImZf9nMDabss3TkG259rbTleXrjs0QAyKj9oT8cuuU/vP74FZaEkgTcmHvf1Ab/a8DlxRmnS9yrikoujuMPVx@uckKuSsRyVSSkqBNYV@p/LsMkODjYq@3lhN90/bEVJbQuE@IBhVxx4m/LiI8j97WNW3jBMiuGwusJLJ2Wk4TgLMG1xqh1t47NnDtV7N@2oE5AutBwZCzY0dApsX1FUsAX7tpdhcyzPWkZW3FbVFnuokY0mUQBMSy@240oXGtZhFFw2pEmArBNTwhtsts0LeI2EBncIW9OR8BP1qPYxCKu1xgVblexhPXtYUZJC3qv0bLWv1jk4AtOFufH8fucbd62fATyfDxGc@S0t3IPoG10AUbqGFLK5vewAQsjeYmhRH43G/f6wxJByXhiJKwa0/qVKhZCISn5loBsF8aW8CfZUea4dLG@@c@fOx/Gbb9rKX4zwXux6FsL4Vp2OUghafpN1bTGQKyVtItFt9v0lT/JY0a83zQAGMZGzLEyX2o6aKbqipXSl3agfgu6pdN2UDS7pUmp8GvzS8luGqUZ/EBsJa/0GYSXiVJOml@KgWU34IerqDuSGDfjom3d3bWHLtey1/zStrtNQ7E86FgsngIzQGfc9orFrgKDe9C42dHynj@3i15rZnmqqiDUh8rhaTuBQrfYxOe6bDdmh1/aE@hfl@HehGE8BYiHfnd1APiAPgtkzNW3Ip3TOEPyZkCe32wWfj0s/Fpo7ux8ac9Uv1vi4q8bK8Uj8TMkft1G5MKv64bFRMJSDVn8wa3/oBViIpbA@kDIpfFaT05h4VdoGa9mw@K/AQ)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)

### Explanation

Alice is a 2D language created by Martin Ender. As well as the orthogonal movement that most 2D languages have it also has diagonal movement. Although we don't really use it in this program each character performs a different operation depending on whether travel is orthogonal or diagonal. Operations with integers when moving orthogonally and string operations when moving diagonally.

Mirrors (`/` and `\`) are how the IP changes between orthogonal and diagonal movement. This diagram from the github explains in which way they do so:[image]

The IP starts in the top left corner travelling East. We travel over some commands that don't do anything besides add junk to the stack until we reach `/`. This sends the IP South-East which we will go through a couple of other commands that don't do anything important until we reach

```
/"78"oo@
```

embedded in the Incident/Whirl/Cow line (The reason it is here and not earlier is because Underload didn't like it earlier). The IP comes into this snippet on the `/` which changes its direction from South-East to East. The `"` then puts Alice in string mode. As we are in String mode the `7`and `8` don't perform their normal action. The second `"` then closes string mode; since we are travelling orthogonally this means the ascii values of the characters we passed over in string mode are pushed onto the stack, one number per character. The `o` command is the output top of stack (truncated to one byte) command. Passing over two of these will output the '8' and then the '7'. `@` then ends the program.

#### Incident

Some of the `x` just before the archway loop were replaced with `"78"` to prevent `8"` and `78` from becoming tokens

Comment: The mirrors behave more like lenses. If they were mirrors, the IP wouldn't go through them.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I prefer the description Martin gave somewhere. The path the IP follows is like what would happen if you were to hold a stick up to a mirror and came in travelling along the stick and then came out along the reflection of the stick.

Answer (score 11):

## 128. Haskell, 4904 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xx 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00@O6O4/m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o<
>-}

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 20 1 ",
# define _ ,
"z c #0C8302"_"b c #B87A63"_"_ c #0000C0"_"d c #708FB7"_"e c #58007B"_"f c #FFC0FF"_"O c #FFFFFF"_"y c #FFFF00",
"h c #E60001 "_"i c #CAFFFF" _"j c #280000"_"k c  #CA0000"_"l c #E60100"_"m c #CA007F"_"n c #330001 "_"q c #E60000",
"c c black", "g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fheyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fibyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fjbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fkggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"flmnqcccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002338 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5018 bytes)

This program prints
**1** in Python 3,
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2,
**6** in SMBF,
**7** in Japt 1.4,
**8** in Retina,
**9** in Perl 5,
**10** in Befunge-93,
**11** in Befunge-98,
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1,
**14** in Turtlèd,
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal,
**19** in Reng,
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave,
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface,
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaVpSeKkP97SpjgVFWgk6xIdpWtPVgc5NaHPImbRg8JwmGLQ6NbWpSavi/mwRmi5M1JEUwJwTSRkAmCnomi6YJD1K0y1F5ia9PvcqJfaqQE2HdIPOC/Ivk19MmlcnE07pGwAZp@l8NVsoZ15hSND0taobAuLhBcNQMTJJ04uCwL8CTQEop0tqOVM5f5XEhuhzIJ3TZGFBcz3D1DnelFTF4l1NV/tTHutlDgXIibwQJVkwKB5oPqM1uwWCGKAPaF3g@hYYJao6jVnoyVimJZrXNLonc8MgT8sSwBZDSVpA1tErSJeHBuQ21ImwTZ5BK4LQpw1N4CVR4knJtLAwBcUACo0gLfFjei7JMt0XZMiwIYf3AzJ6amxFWYUHqb5K0fDhtVfEr@8OBYBRBIcBggacQwaoyGjghsOHuc5pGhAJTGwA4aY0AXmRTLdBC5whoURCFkNQ@oR32lpWVZpTtmtJzySO5oDeqU5wG4KODRAkeOmhoAuAkltLi2euSyawAFmboWsCp9NNXRC8u3K7UyQUpmIJJlYkSJru9NRdqBbd0IRWjiCnmdSBHmneXFIcHUzTh08n8E27XCdUoZKnvxw@YNgSU2hmTfdwXjr9G9pgHh4E@C7YHjPQXyjASgFXZJpRNZPhAhoQGDCBQIbDIIYCs3BQk7cKpk9ftcWWYFlQfWgNuqTQbT@pGT/VdeyKG6ZyY6i0rCoD4CdUVp8qyA@FjoegCXgVepKfFmbANVWx2kidEw43hxI0moFNsiX8lkIhDAWVArJnc9Qp11DlKYGDnIaJAghcgayIsSTSbVrkJBmzQDqisqjWBWMqm5hnqvSx5UFhCP0g7ZDBq30EmqgzKI4DpCQC@tFkq/cRogAYGkIlVcWk3/3rf9cfDABPhudVvW@La5vuqzxRfRwhFvQJjQKrKpxMyAI4P5ZuZYcCZpws9TkTi1eWdhGECFLqXJ3KfVqFAvW5BF1ryM2gO4qiwJuCJeSWtvTTE25s6QzJklyo@ITrQcOSAkjZpNoB@nMOWokXqAMiM4HJ1BSTdEAr0G6D@cnz6djz6eODAMR5g96jQ4YZnIDABY9IFNy5vyY57cyWNgPlYnKGKvUpbWkOVSVMB3jaxadVTVA87h0cbr9b77m9QdRlHu@JlOaDoqT0PW6Q8SyU6/ae8Gn@Xjp@PHmVe7tEwDJHLNhbBQ/vdVGgcUifmDETTlKC2pJuB@zQVppqPCHHMTm4FY18eR03syIOyGCBYqmifIAaChqyIGieUJD1opZAuL3VxoR9FX2Fw67wsfTocx@4fdtVJxigpjsVxb7alFTUWrI2nIKOBqYohgbaW0fR5TkQHgOVuAkjtp/uEbEmmh8UC1GJc8GtC3QP9KgjRqRHWj0O8wdQT9oYNj3Igdvt0EJ/qz@DLoAubRpvlLKszqFgQhsOXaBBFCycG0ATQWarQhmrQlaJJGa3amMF9Api6wl0MtCToC9grwPVbov@Vh0BPBK2YACb1Ve2VNCEWwIW3hoSN/2GlkToUhPQEvqS5gVUPaCDBGtcwUKmpBsaYKug1RIKhGOx3a72pqeZOpMJ3IGuXjFf7VBY@cyOhQADkCjMaZlTBlNugOaSAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30etghkQF7DA0aQ@rw8@uyyVhij65bZaCut1rPHhE5VDK2wRSQQafSnG3y0X1JB@0kL1@XDgCzV4W7fkaQHQJ@dr1DgmMIgJAJC4GfmqDcQJDnQ4kfguwidYqlHq2x6HXxELVdOij4gLguGolhz34MU0FmHYVkvIsigC36Fg@MsYjqbCeCNP52xNcxc8ZkD2J1TSKMB1uxQYYLguzZTAPrqYGWGww2jqlEetbanFvzExgMXR26KQjL0DQ14xh0u2QOp70gNCvT1Jcls6pgyzKmvpRM1Qr3ZLUHutSAzsQ4JTD8tCctXtWIxK0ZPjKoGRhNokGnYbR9noKIeNyiAVqOxOcQeCvJRbQtQWH9ugCQAAWBUx7RIPqzCBqgsVR4jytI5D4IPcTlp13Yy1xeCGCuNV9y6gRVBt0hgzlaZ1kd1IwIqsVW1ERPc3uHp7XCJraY2x0cqZLi@eL@@PGj@9h9Bur448dPEDrF0CcM@SD0iYQCJIRwQQyRHH4SwtR7kgPjHt0v9w7mhfcRm22BQ8lK0jzc/fFx5NHP3bP2NYxXL@glUEMAHcAL4HF702kMer2uszlUNNgTrdrXLc72iTTUBWVACQtN1U26Us0XnmqZ5kXaxUwNnZGlHqPAYPg0ge4Gkw7Xnvwwe3CyQ7CuqmaaNBjGE@giANmzKspUp9BBYbIgTSSzRKYpsoKivWk0JzUH5VoIStsTElFXJ2v1YlACP1Rp12HEhYb0zkQQx1w7NYqpU3sauBWfwPgJTuGCPDXgeTqgWrfrSBswiYA4rQvCLIoa@HwISaZ560gbMkVQ4lQvqPecyC9s6AXj1/O8LSW@jXFf@vuZCG/2TEztQuNYYl/tCfIiHg0Ishg0F6sgdvN4lLIudKD/HsSevNRitS8DZUKfDSzEVwmcTlkUNmGgKMO8gC5LBpnHbzcntRbsB8pldbzI7hDg2qSEN/bafiPTtY2FCCEIwlhFNbcJPYFFFdtBAfPjtzlFyRiSnx3QNxS9TSG5jUlPJD97AI5twwWsIJxFI0sucQ6GtpOqwox7TsAmqqJapACrJIVj6uQShPFuHz27w8oOMT1BnMK8jOlJCoa/ARZIJQmk2OtJ74ECX5B057oHTJ/29rENhGv4xvKgdxhvTnVTFvr29b/9cR8a4G3zDLklzCf48TrwBHzDpgqI77aWnRVvyM/@liUwo6kscYQNJPQtlDyHcz5OXgf2o0ZVSgcCQ06Hxl06jQvCiT8wLH5FzizKdUGe9gXnur8QwuJd@8bKrUgTUiO4orFGxr93sr@yzqz8OGfWZZXrEyzWWoYkbFrbahdhwQ2gcsyWRgJN@B10OkYUvVm8AAPEnFq/uF7xrXaVNPx@rb/akKEY12MFmOlxPekdLiIR8ffk2uouaDAERJkbW8EnDO6vqlUZXRoMwFCyr@@BgQkLswyN4wVmTi7vqhhlamhWU2DoK/h02fp9D8RZWF0H3gOEasrk59eIHREEHvoGkorrhYEtFkmvmCpzvSUaVcNfLz9YIBlHQb2keZ8vFMEhdT3B3KxMatr7@dEGIPlTqf25rUVMgoBXRVEQvtVnYdyRJpwcCPe3gu@qYMcI3YT2gI64GQfmqcwZICCmzWZhBs1Cfr4mtDiU8FOZ0zehr4jshhxnHeG9qegmjybxqizZkuncvKcLX88LNmhwiZr8bLLi3Vv@9sEUx2E6sA7t79Aqb@J08B05@g71ZM3EcK67JRhB9T3e8eocv@/23qE6E6zf/UPWai9V36F@AjKRDJjevc3e578lrriuSH72c3G8lyqTl/fGH9PXqqrDVNygw8EQGjgKWQyHAVuWrdlms1R9X6YNSVYNukF@v8YLMPkNw/rdL83bbJM4JcAPrT62Du/PtpcoMrzRGfL7TuNy8kCV48kBw8HPuxIw1UXU8vb1ezXcWkOx7Dc11NrcURXWvr6r2sfw/y3hIMucOi4obAW/YkXtU2f2RPT9CsKMAJf09leuGEqSnEHGmqe91wA6P5xzS@f6jxg93uOuM3poS2IsgzWHGVJJCJi6ZUD/Y0qLfr20/vfpqDdoE9@qxFbjjmUBNDb5fdOkdDjE/socbCj0/RpLlKfCVNirQaq9kQBi8zXd8f1EhexqHNorFQwwD3c/11Areyr4XVTjeI53X1U4nCxBJ/@mNbNX1WhgYWs4da5BoIaBtxkHylTbadwt3tWnSv3rnBtqTs9W@ztEYsqv1UjJb9tMO2a4IZDvfgVyjPv6MOFVJ2BDKN/R/jZSsghk/e4gJjEbzCMJ15f0r@I9ptcrj2C/gj0CrSqNjQAuUn2f4gm/N1MnwKkUzMUUwVzi73vc3qdIe6oq/5rWAX3al9BMA@MT3QC@1UrHdGM56YHlxm@WRb@jBZxpInALp8TvNmwNUJrfiTPydlXvK6PU1hrf3pLPVfns9OwbjV7HvssGk8HEVwGd5S7GCbzTBQmyVDDyPeaP5ti0ZAUUV02tddKNq8LBK/WiLYExUj9g8ENhIpDbrxj0XH80NZzLu0ALFb97koMMWfPc26aSYH6Drw1TVQTjq0CkXs7q6d5yShNuIBS/KTubJQTcHeR1aSe4fzHh2BJ2HrJ9QzFYEztVGQtLw7nuN3@XPDThdPJVbPu6LY8rld/sp0Fm74rxN6w4ZagOlaEw1BlD5zd37/UZEELTck76esspQ84Y43Zo4DZXq21N24ZkWmfvHBC3kPXOoeG3/VkgTtJt7wVj7SJ0UFJ4XSD7iM5WFX2Au5vTCcxcTVUP0gTO4@F8Pq@XsjLh5GegAJgDRZw0cOfW8v8waJiSmgRWEun7e/rwy@I4dMy@0GnadeyiHx8trGQPsbDQiHdF3cp6f8g9pg/dgYD70P2gHNMhNwEVZLBF94JyO3CiRC4WnZuq0wo3IZvFGHZqemLtSMMUEZ0@hpzSlwW6BcqVTJxV3dpXtTbvm7hW@l//vm/7wgwEqOREMsD2GCjov6VOhKE6/2SVa5ee0TQOfWkQx3yIi4FYeiCXoY25ZII6IS4wMINtFZtJe0fd9i6Dmxr2sC0qrEZFvY5@HqbVaBY1fVWwBMcueJ3LqRSvytOJQs@lvjk0gjDfU3iB7Nivt3kghGCKqasoeH66RPcFXKvqI2FEmcmqOib7UUjJf/17y48AEiUUIQw7xRM3oq0SaVTQZPOe59UpUO0gWQm6aoN4kMnQu6ZoBoDYC1a8l@aHHHFwAEkMONv7WIy1xZ/LNOhAgXajGxzuQ55IoucwUz9v34ce07@hJ4zw3/6Y8X6x@eb6IZBgDZefdkBOXlCutpNDkLxJddOuw4XLrhY6XBH/orVQ2Z6THgyT5nK26yfEV4vInTAn2/XEJ0NB5YFOUIoB/QNuvQS11WnSh56pNSgFGiYdQ19BUPgchCzvLuL2glvPmOVwQf9CD1FWAjzNxkJwZzFERm@HSTrr7DREtjeDmLzQm5Kl0Vk4GI6kSXUOn9IwYGNIF/oqOh/d//SwCIcCD4tE4ZExHOY8PCx@CIVvgXuqDrl@ZLADFSr5L4fBs9AvvxgwCXS5Xtwn1uYY9PLDL7VSrdBoZpqtBnDzxarsQVHVJ9xGU6AsaDJMz4eqTLy6gC26JBjf1h5rDbK@A3CPhz7k6FP0@fR61wlrUJvVroDr0AquQWAU2c79jez78hvCVvpbAFsziRJta1G6RgTJlhm3sa1B/Y5sYbtgd5@CznY4gvude1Qh4ZGLTgOXAsCl7@QR/baWVgt@IhHQjN9m1Ndx7EMBvNpAvAVAJq3Lwvpa6Vbl9lb@5Z@hxhqMa//UGhMcX60xQnytxgC4yUZyFDOlcqte2M0E4rRx4S0swDQBRSySvmU5A1rSpdqOZ45mgoFnaLmncPJGtxr0TDKkniwQeRNxZJBBuWB3JDskBmoXGhVZkM7IBmjyfh9UU29pomYDlR4ke@LWxnhAoV0HwKzgeqD10y4KYY30Wwck0FxzmEDxP1uZDwkcwWxQexwmHwTmd//631lOkg8mhP/UDosQ/ldW@CcGGfTW0cuicc0aZEu7VKMNGC6tik@4xVadcMTCEVFSpgItTYCDM8IQBLeI3dR3g8dz3wZ@QiMAM1H1orYl5Qn6owc9f44ZBg2MgSqLQbKvKiygHUBZE0eg5yk6rcIAwcRj8SjLAJGBmYMwIFkIA5qF0Os9BlmjZpKW/rnH06enp7TLgIm0kI6fWIxkDrmfIq6f14QeAixl2SL3NOSBLJsckHZmZ/Mccj7Wi1mxy7lZN/14AmaG1S4wUnlIAEC8GK3Y/HDBUKjarIJGV4SFSdT50rGxwMBRiAOIYLkuO4gCgMjCjb6Vr2V3s2GHbgxb0hzcbgZXB8EaCHbs2ic69z/RD@aD8mi72NIgMP9hjyApEP6zPX63a@nJvPX49Lz218Ta0J8biopbuEWglvaEmXCEYePerZ7islEBvdgvfgGU0BOgZ/GCNFI1I5MrlC6rtcYbj0UC6X4N5qbdZ6e@h0DQf/@4DrhfSb3D1GyRaVxniw4rt6narIUgxGZB5DWZ@0p7Tek7pXes3dK3ZZOENwWxoe9FTCaYgSJZM3yLfZPKbAHmrN2cN6V6vF9e7h9Pzx6UgzfF/7LPmfsgeITCBaEHg7hyu@k9Oqfk7AE38SkbI@i4E4Vdm0cV1s5S1v0m@n0/xvUzOxtvRme3GX0Zw2dMX5gxylSWqeA7@9BQ9yBjFUUc@SzCHHpB1zikskjqpkCeerOXt00Nbdfl7eNFtv/XmklVa3pKnKo5BWYmusRb0AZR0NYklngAwzSmZG5mPjCbwhULMsFbkskMqIr13lhfIvN2Tncc09YpDWEiBZoOPag4Nr6JoMjQ5w5m3UNZ6p1w6fsFvfam@prbYtDQZMn0oL/gIoiTRKiNx4sVYE9lAd0NT1OPtm8j7bgg@ogXY20K/KqpGr2ZmOcFJ1SHuRmdnwJyEAOBvpxOAE4kl7qAo4RAV9QAZAY@uh0i7qEUj12H4KQfg9KDQ2HRlwYw0ni8flBJP7Dsxv@R8/pgQu0GPWyx6hw3/bYZ86t8Nrc4xt1zQUnpCwsPOtMfPyJ3IN4978zcXtcbGSCOo7YXaf@1B6mjLDjT7rUb78tXCiGVWiuC3b6TSgWHBoXebjCvgBIbpl6GIIyhHnHCabRnSlxwDTpIk1vPg0fxG6bupQNnOJ7NaYX2@ciMBC4kIUiTnCIJSTIucnnwKRMPk4Z2xlhD6eNlJWn0PRsMPkKYFOKlD3FNIQfmBs7GvRQYnJDlmKCFARj@jpGiOcy9kCLrekiKpXBBQAeovcmkIw@GpAMCL0it6bMf6Y022PRAi6up1LHdGrvqMEWDWJzu0RiAdo@acyxO4K/tsgRcQyUGUDmYakqgUD5fCYoC/dUDMjOB3klzUxAy3et3Hm/0b56eISUcWCRe2D5QQOjuUzUF9xdZBXvmkDkh89qTFxj3f37AgV@0h/4l80dMkDn54jmU00sGjDHvmedwmGZ9kSOf71A58hwqaI78@CNOh18Owdp5CrqCrgUABQ5l7wnIM1hH6UPl5JA79Rz20@EjkgNufT7vF8jwG4MJfjnkXpjDH8Ga8EOMbvVOz6Hhxe4QCgbZF6APe8gh4weZ@eJx0S7ycCIWfyj5fEhD8PAJCfgN89DwkXHlocGQmfeJbeQyg4mjRnZtlXVLvHnY0mKgHX281ugx4stqrYY/OcDbD9XsSdtnH/3hDwdsHCZRn@IRj/opHPl4dEAffHYxRy7d9eUhPztx33NiOPj8WBvXarfeB4/7IFd1sVEX1OanE/qIoQ6Yo9AvCYb5@eefwfqk78@CZ8FH733A/XjvWZwlEkcn/njyyP/Zz7r9Jwe0zIZY1usJh70M/dCgHxIcd@SLhj8rJ5IkaUa/D191iI94gSWWRin5AB8PW3O7YxF34yf0Gv/06SP8kX/4rG/x9yOJsaMJyNvPRy/teV5QB2cfFt/7eYJvNUuCbYZlww84Y4vEP37@AFUWfORzfPyZzGNoVyLpUtXPCEwPD1g2RqsHMPItBLpHLxYB/FAH/GJxsIJE9mBJ/p4wzLKQhTr4TTrt@87PYh0KBp@cEHXw8@nP6X/ChzqAicbB2dnjy4svcB/8CZE/@gK@0/vT0@DZ2eIs8Hh2Tx18oQ4WL9RB2AXy8nBEHaQXp3VCwX3@zKbl2Z4ZlyF8Gni8r5XB@m36w6eBg3Axk/OHG63sAQt3sc0tJkbwtl7I5KstgK6VC5lG4bzULrRqEG88Pp19/uwLAiM/B88egZLFD74zX9o0Tfru6ShIf/XztCdk3VIH@bNFiwmcArFlO6ZOigk8wN2DFwr7hTq4P7j3fAp/Cofk0CzEjtnxtVrd/FerEC8tQiNVDw1DQ7aPrRoSWqFlaLkITdQq24egAH@hz9V4NcpMIEIKiYvQIKSEFJbdwfb@/6SqXldVQKhCNnMRMhF3SITroFq9BmQiFD@CPykUCi2AzEVoBv8hmcgZ@9NTCGvoDT08UPe062cB@m@QdQdD7mDc7ZYeY3Ht@ctLOP58T0b3WOrxXlhI5qOL9rufHu5TqZT78eSAMR4eGEulucJR1wmCvLw8PeUzzczTE4OLHYvTQ99nX@AzfNJnvlP78umgf4acDZ5@fKDcnnmn08FvZz6bWyESsOI668TtGxKAz@ydvLuBxX5Z8HjuY49fXrxe74cH94nbqonHQwtgs3pc7MMiLNJhl5cYsykYCdgI2hvxmPfsLB6D@3jSG/CESLKV5cGladqDK0gmx0HivZBOZ3SdWxKgKAxGDy5Of3pw3Ycf0@lUjETHAqk4reqBVMTr8np/Yk9P7TLCXoh2uRcuVXfTX162/zxfXk495OPFP68XI@3fM68Hkr0xuFt88SxOPacejIMozPXl5QyDBO4LhO493kfvy4sVB78e76mF88wLvMMVgH/Gf9WgDY12H7wcoBGh0NGY19NbCt5o3JP0pey/9EeogMcVcUegXi43576//3wUOUpE7z89Hj0eeU6PgkcPZ487KtrrPqBBlh3ZS7MHyDfqIHhSd7Fhlxtl8QSX8lVZCMoww4@kTnaFwf3kOXr9SbIp35Hv8/1RKmWVfXT0y0foNoAOCnPB5wDkl/bQp2ena6HaoPSewfcLbTMZwi9fQM6sNLBJPPZi/cPDImR1R/qklz78csC9nBD89IvLfbIjrwS/x31CdnNcX1yHnH7PPrpeXIdfei9ovB2xXmIjxKInJ0dRK5xInsBYzR7ZKSFI8VqLlTFIEQyOJz335ADFyQ0890Kt0j1hIME4p@0wyReLxZgw/C5@iBfCC@oEdz2sLRZXwGV1IDqZIvgOaMNIUTA/6EHLz@lECEZBWeZ0WhXFj1Y8THToniCArSnIMi7X4TwAzGG5P4e550fqABQNWMGGAJ9JjROmgjCfTufC@pOTjGNuRHtGMI/Fz@9/@1f/Ar5/D98/t65//n@kYvj7@9/@z//b7/7mbyHyv8D3/4bvf/79b//tH1tfcv8P8P1/tuL@wf5uwVlfCnD9D7//7V/83e9/@6/@Gr7/q/3969ff3/3lf7L@/1/7D4N/@7u//Af8sW4A11/92e/@7Z8AiX@J4X8JYfi3o/8UgrQvYH18W@n0L4chsKToh182kX9K/8KwoO1pZh0JWP/9Lw/o5sVakA7OX5gQC9EW5J/9/rf/5u8gdgfyT5zsn2mIew1pi4NT0J8C5N/s0GlD/imVoFs1@KmXzi@aW9dmIZO7oOJ0tlrJv7rEbKAYXS4Um@vbhJXqZI2tUXQL5fLrW/vSVac0z6F4CTRHW0qYg3ksnmERxE5LUWdfAqfUWaPQhORmlU4mId66X@B9JIz31FmthRGlCr0k6bd4rdXahsulwm3ghaKwJ3ykYwm/PxgMwg9e/eRDrsHDnxwQ9n0T5YC6xuXWFGvtfkuYA0K6kML9PuhAc4Vst/bwqeqp9n4kXDAKg7o0GMIkb66uAQzDgKFzPZS@GVg71AV02Ak@mojPsJto58P8P0QFsXuHw6lkLJmKhJP@ZCoZjbHxWMzPhv1sIplIhfxg4SfZeDKWYv3JaCoSjUZTfpoNx1IJmA8qfUlkGDAWWZeLJgFJ4fHZnVN8CEoNDs@og74gwiT7A73w9L0fDvpOBD1N0q5I8iFEuxjGReFuyNHi/jH9xRWO0Ak6HKJZ2uUHw9wGf6L9lGtF8/RBKJeMhMKuJ1cP77LJRCYegbsnkgafXAju@niXCCWL2QTcCXgXS4ZCiSzciXhXLOZCxSLcVa07/MDd0rkLhaB01xBvC3HACtQ8uSS8zWUILP3kGuFtOImFQuIY7jDVvpXtrCy5m1g5gQIsRcG7SMRB@7wuhRTKw21P5vgxPuA7gJuBDkrV5Yc5Kk8aHYIqBNFXSDE5zCIOheXbz4okSb13k0ZbSdVltV/tVeFDksaDgZMyqK4/JEmeKM/8mw9JEkUVoKxZlorXp@pCfbKTqk6Sda1W@acn18sJNj8KIr30eL8Q@9RDG9JKgI7iCfmnYJTFPk2TrnjCdXwEV9cnVwSCCw8dcsMw63I/uFze@9TjJ1ci5jqGGWXA/SP7CeZtKdexK5Fw0d4TVxikOOZyxelwwuW6g5FJGATc9CfXiS6YU12hwycvSMEqHTohlNDPHrxyfvzteb/YYL2TF1yyAjKfPSufzw9f7yekGKxLMJi9x0sYz70nL9ATGLtPQIBiT8OgcjBn2lrqAuikawNgdcZ1b6LBkA4GafjC1BLTtbTFDo8r5aHJCJp6cNkGhrUA4XG7E2G32@s@ASQfadeWCvKeEJJpi7Uehz8u4AjwJwX2sM0ETyoA1hodSEEFLJL@uy2a9PGxYXI6LkmRIo9pVzzlwmgAOU1ZZZ3FekfHfjbg/0xZpkOcpQ5eqD4@IhNN0SepE5xmgk17emZTd0UvEwPfxRa9J9ShGyl2R3as/APye4hj1EEgokbVg8PDQ5jZNs9cEVc1@HTK2HPUM4ZMTh/OTnzpaM5HJnxBZwp8hjP6N59olNIF9H3o4xFE1qwhGUO@DGjjANCd@P4xnyCUmwak1Akalq4DDUWfl5e4okA/WLSe/uaATCvo2hdnL3qqkOXy42tsNu64QR5EvH@kvb@pSPKXZCRwRhaXUM5oaKiXRuqnxE/Jn65b1Va1@Dl0nDxOPjy8nSd/Bp0t1QvUgfGLV42xv1EuTw6ONXck6o7AZDh9YFWbTXgPzsKJoMEtDx5tFy5PNIGiBvfEyAyz9IHY2f3Md25mE7JgAEUl/6g/GEjhP7r@@ZdDhnG7aZo9jP8mcGr9n8JPrmqV4YrHXF70bTN@evrp6YAGW5F2hWMoyT6GtqzBbdvVszhSyJ9wZJA/QdhEGHDr3GG64D1iGKYdhqEulYon4wfUHxjma5tCkLpeJRUFQTemk33LpBlduuZwCVlZL5VC4Hq6EnS4OgcCOWMijYMi7gPgqLgdZw@UW1HkHK3duKXBoCsKxoJxgicukUPYaBF1gwenQiZxKaCP8BQz9LjzUl@oD4BrypvEiwV@TijqA7pT4K3HgfPTPxqmF7eaQ17qwwdb1xlm0DCfEDlmsiMD7AkFthGwh@v3DRpXsMnOseWmx6FzgqpZntjykrYyGUSZWwM88bDDcrcIPqJFiwqozRFNSiSUY@Ws4j9YYL2piKQUS@UC5KHTtEh2QuzcLr2HR2CQ6n0UvXbhdAiiEAuCE04RcAQEdBDpIbi9E/QF5D0E0kezmC6SHRWAAnPHTyjx06Kd8R5vHyE7ohd5WTUAsVW6x6oBffRkF2vXwRlCsBLAQqwdUcxknNEHvN9uPXw2@f7RS39xPI48mEqf0uGNS5SNCxrDOmqOZOQnfUtwyNkiNpsJNvbRD017YnmueNZwdsyGUS/UkemfnFhNpZ1QVx7e@wVX3E9@M/nxR/4n7X7yeOKdpE28@nwTGCfGHskCOTLTkzSIh3YvPZ6Y9z6f9JieeK88eA9DEAysL5RoMdvw2nWDmitpoAV35Qyvf3WvBH6jPPqL94oPSJ76j@7SKz@XDvkX8JXSrF/2P6dZux5Qpple@ZQT7hS@uPi/4xUEY6aPO9mJwixjj5xe3XOPaeCHDBl9viJUBug07mWf79ELhcuQ@Dbjifzjj5xPPlucyIGAF6F@inwq3psQePSl8f7Yw50uPq3up5D/2APXNBQje4F4yGfz@mVNO9B3Ajy22nRDukXjAslbAHmTdPro7tPR3VH648fV/SIwefRb7D8ObaQBiV8g8SdbXleeozsv/YolZHnC4/pBOv4heGSAdS2BDXN059e2cloUHt1BigYDn031C@pLcgKWs7GEEmZ7CllnlpBTD8iMjBzUZZDDCc0@@kxC3ozBS5INbjm7ahLMZTj0l/fTiqoEOAKBafaJfJj4sPj0iXKKtt1YoGRULj2cAsKciBzIpONaCTnd0fKA/5Z@3aeGHZ27nqA0SncFGiZDkfhWdyWqiXQ4Q@fvEQTVwJfQy4mlsSznJVA2RHsADNEeCBdALYJMsvWEDZm2E6G1nAaCXKgnRMtNHw/NMFA/gXrb9HxQIRYZ0Jn3kCH5R2mim0CeJAjR0ikpDwLQVagPUAmkAesgPdJnoMjoH3@k7dvTNEzwEjgWIBjCjXwsAr2hFAr/DkoBB1I5AhlFfUgKAdo@YAq63O0UFP2nFWR7zHogg2/ktxxng8Rx1jNVDMtfHPnmtcjAtvjwYQSmok0Q/BM7GfJD2ssfDuzh/pjOVa9rrWahfp1pwC/Y@8nNoX/H6@Ph3pwzpeH5UT1JIQ5mPFdnhe4lzBM9YPWBSKl9PPyxT1@2yjARr@T9@CgisP7AWuOAAfV4jUkwyAEvRlDVB8xcGkvM7tGweFAf8WUjB9EGnFP7kBwyOMsbL/aNE7uB6xEwmNvPT@2cGzoRDMM@PivgHB9Kjkgl/vwTdEuHXmgft0XcBJydTrKvjsuEfuKtoUsDiZwJObQQ7OQnJyOZVnbSPyg8JqvPmRxKNJWC6fUxHfJjgHUCYScQcQJRJxBzAnEnkHACSSeQsgOsg5m1MMO0LBKJb4KJTTC5CabWwWhoE9xgiIY3wcgmGN0EY5vgprTourR4kuClDxxukq4r6JjGRpNOGj6nopgkMgZo2NeRUSA0/AYSskffREJ5yd3IRCpkF1RiqggUDsc396B9HNi0x6LKb9Hht0q27uxIGKsoa5ZDBLag66CVCgs8xA@EzntMo1cuRYHapXlZ4MAYEEywUtJFkH/Be2w9raIvjzeeuYghza7vIbsAU1PIw5LzKC3x2ZMc3pdsYQvvxWY9EESvGbPl1mwTaVF5vDPSWhijO3HbWD@igkWOvgMRtiCwDXb9oJ0ym/p0b5GRrxe5g3BvkW@IsvDG9uVC3ngI8rSTlYz/BFvaKc@yUwTS2mAG2IcPExl41aD42FL6C3vs@v1v//p/p3//27/4W/p3f/O3/99//p8w/J/w5/8Em4UOrwH@/C/w59/jz/@CP3@DP3@5lYnAR45dv/vr/wC3/@N/pH/3L/7CSvo3f@fyR9eIIAWjNjn/6l/iz5/gz//l8sfWgH/1ZxYgZnH5X6gd08oDUH/@X2gaSkMsa2R//fc07fKBgeGxJe/e6uOPWw85WAjWbLgnocfX6dYvP9SR7SGvzwV47Tt2c@fDBvBuIdc5PE130/fAnLGc61BL8xw/REd2O0o10P7h0YRRjeAA5G3eB6PHXh5wQ@3/e/qYdvsQBqLJ01ppS4fb9bfr7dqkIqzPxQB1eOadjQrD3jUlML2lQL7JTGBpBHHaQmakrCUjNn8reFq3M4C4HMmSTA/rpeyynNww6aHtQ0/hfzPVRaHFYch62okcPkzZPtnsVoE76uZVs0Epr2Ngyrh5/mE7K4kQJho0CWRb8xsZizeEC/7X6DYtZ3ebQrX4qsPgpwcm5nhbI60LStMu1zdgkdM2vBctrsguvEWvDXAfOo487jxNsQ/YdXt766K24kIoQ3rfQzBsVcpSGeskdjcpvJUU3koCmi2cRNfEwuFXNJCBA/Xi7pNDVrYtFbWbbSNc2HOcdkAyYC5oLQj6RXlqDNNvURONvKvs3iLfQsk@pu1@8qAQnXNGu7xvMgDO3Tzp1225H3XoDczbhtqfE7m9E7PTWu9j2smz1SkI96jXXFq3HJva13K7BX4FNfvo@86CwqF/YkGB7ywoHvt2Qa@bFfPuoH@fv99WO46aWGv4DTKr4x/sDFA4NP41iN5GHSHFOgl6vDDlydhTnt5cpT17DsyFeMY5i2DnlFx964QCnMRUVFOwlgc@aypMOVS0greOxN/37gr7BPqBouqCsf2UlGR5nCtufE6PVwcKjGp@PBNBss9rxh1S65nt3XFlPbLZVmjOOmUfUVuMQsvz6UlSJPPpCYxPWfRuGIi3QR7dgN0UHs8Poa38nrVpW9U8Kp7lYnq/jZPYu1a2psSPPVXNTnRDIRkaJnS8IMPkix5y/BhfNEFYglUkzyyhRdozPV5k4lCdqANBUfERRcz9Cn1pgxsJ4jSN0OKnOT/Nb1FkT6I9vJ/z2lmvfnVW@irs4bzr/OFdBDvM8NP6ax4jZ/U9xT29W5yVzSmv8evpbWzT2/g6vaKkG@Zrmkkkrvbg9dcVHfFsMADghozIt8nw208lvyFnh5R1NB5EbWX4bhL7gsHD8IeUZgA0Y4MHRZAP//rOgLs14e33@P/1BnSyF763@Ygx21iCvpkU0PYjUzSDnNqg8IIHwEte1D1vi1uLdv47y7InOmSG56ddRHEp6E0OHVPTBMVYb7Q6iL8h8@i68UbuiT9H2krcQ5M@89Pj8PtNlH/qCzK3FPoeG9K/hdepcV3g@kRffV/FUdERpadap497Qn52xxQjT/0QoON3RIbzz7ze98XKApHW0kM24wiFpff5RxbuXqtmXARNW3sgqg4a9IA87k8OWdCW2tJ6UlC23lBi61Fr/LFasoIPUH6TIcAH6/0TrH9TrPdr6rPuWVfpO0aENWxwt8r4MJCDER/HeduGv45F364pWWVYZ0o7rbxjnbzX4tLXWnxLKhyZtKyS7xPJbwndd8vclqhZyDYqLPfrhpA3mHOcLPO8ZxujFfPVFlOVNzoB47DFVOWdUeVpj0Jd5ySazsSzaNOWfeGlJAiW4DqDaxuuiBDmoE@WQDl1Q7vWWfIiKRNO27Ja7Jh7Hm3RLS56t/cRt6AoJ4wLuS/rMvl3y@TflMnvlLnuAbtFbgFR/E6Rditg83ytCWRBNN/RzpiEM3e4fE1tw0dROR33Xr@4Jfex5KfdM/cxKGS34D4ueEApu/vu4zwJGO7jBgmM3cdXENj0Lfcv7mOnWyCADrck8BnjbRWO97z7OOfxvlDkvVROuUH38bpNAeaTdUs48mItr/bsXX91vaoqCH7LqPTTKDEGXFSs1v2jn3xD8E9A7TN0IPFjmg4fEWCcgOwMGlsjhlUODBtB8uIbz77h49hZmrLXNzZrKJDuS28tqqCUTIk@ch@4d5WRRRimksVHuAKBqDeP91NEs29mZt8ixy4dJJQ08m75hHtBYg/0PST9HoC3F3HkTX6nvXZRWA34fXRi5vfofEOOUxyhCJ0BvHvIQqb@7P5KpbCtX53HYrX@dgu9XSPARgw4IFYrEbRbOh1sOLRNSWGaqu0KCUnF3T5pOw9@7E6J0vsqG9EKds98J5lE2zVDxbDd@b1fq85WPiRtRwVh4n3o0epl63GB6GJM2ui6LUvV6nxAwpbO6ZNHqQUU27wdJHCWuvGTseK9YcjJaxVJNNeumoTMQXywZcqZVumbfRl83OXXTV@dnGCCA42IYCvnuhRLv6q/wn5XLfvdMagdJrwqYJ9hvX8ofWtef3WUfUW5vCn2bQNiop/Oe/caR@sSNiyH2cGWZf41WXtj4uPLCSwj3yp0jf2Vte@wbT0n@AbfXs8tLFxoJeiz3cgxLsyOw@8z6q1FIs@CjtESxJJsPFbF15RuqvZ1Wq2K72tiTMExGi6/uoH13QbebjzERyqgv2K51cvx5Uxkn2Ldt3FNfWvnwtp1UNFLbH260FYkqHviv7Z20YKI6lM9X62UuzDoJhIJ79utCOy1kHczjlNf3SZYT1vCfjxKgrzfEX0nhqpufnxQXG9dykgEGAMc2bexxM/u415bl23p81d9F/JZsFsctXGNN92A29FKaOpwOGRLNl9NYIhgeo44G4lj3gK//WS2hrtGKB24ofP0RIavpyd0znl6skcxbJr1NtIfDuwXsIS3XtJ4sOvN9M7LcXEBYDqxXhFoL8DZT2JbfigH@DrO9at117mmiik5zg64PoRbVGvPCE@E9Vpv8XRirJdtgqR6wlGcwoZj@JyglQuhceGTuFba5Xy0DB08ZtDQVMV@G@fYemMrOfTQcJZeCdlTZc4RNxCrFPJ44xZFlkOWsy9GXrBHDjK13mbIKdYSssMbPy0MgmTHJ5yCKcdY0qyThtauH4aXZCIEEx8t4HFPFib4kjuQ3T2rydcStMqwKA0GIEiMfSis5eDSxPfeBVQxkNu8rrhNXlVon9Bm@4SR0xHtdWBgp2fnCASDDsfBmkr5gbObLzAW3WRoPOYgRJy0CBR8E3BJWMGkfyvvR8/Su3tlnY8X8X30PGHLWg9TSdA6Moi8ssVn@xmrraVpe9OS6IGtnUvnNA/KPn0lTfYpg@ijpnlcBy7njBMMWm4TnMw7hwN48FiKY@qDQhQPeoDRvOVbAwaugkYb2V7zrl1SFfoHOhImr6qC8oiVSooFHNbO3g52SIOsSKzl3WcrGNcPfdcPuJlIfThAXWjJGuZ3RBnD5Ky2jSzTH2101oYKdmWrCzg3sa2bCEw1Puwp@KPH5QMsPpfXtYMJ4O3djw@W5n2bFZSi9w9Msx/vFNVMJtOcsHr9PDPIDDP1LtxnQ2VfZxQtMEzhQu5n8qXe8lxNNGdiONTs3mR7EV8t0V9o0sUkd6EVKCnanfjuIovURXQVy0VyGT50K56XxWgidyveGkJGFlLMbDS@6Qt1rcfqhnRVua7UV0yxddMe3IzEu05nlFAalFa/yw5uFsJNsqPM2q1UybgR2rmKOa6MzCm7rCY68dZcMbLtZnZ4uSzNx4tSXO1KsdyNkGiL2sWcX8Y0/qJF3c2aw3jjYjlOsZP@MpMz@t2Ez8d0c9lB8oLv34mXjdxVf6DHerFxI8VFZpNLUVsOry6U5/Io15jxPm1ULMVnlFIrzeZCtDPuyRfKXb3d7uWztfmYNe60/ijauZ6avaQej0SmGWE4isZKU1NPlrOZq4SZz5TaRfm2bd4t28kaZV6YzUTrkk/JvlnV5CPTfIsxQu3FpXTVmMcvwk31QrmUS6Pa@Hx6XpO16TgflarNSVQf3BZ7ajh8cdOYXXTLlB697HST9VE4mecXPHMVU9VJpJmqlPXrxTT7XBU6Ob6RFXrxUDZ2W2BH19UlX52V6/VOTeu0JgnjipXviqERVb3lG5nsuFieJNlmZVlKnpca01yutJj1wuJAzUz7ncj1bXxergilzg0TueCm5rVPylVlZnR5aSzbravSbcW4g259fSlFxeUi287q4nM@Z1zXy0xFHw8b0ZHS19oJKafyl7VS1CyNMxfzzl2qlB0LYq03VsfNjtyZmlJ@xBSpZW580@oJ86K0mnOFaLl9w4wKdd5MZAaRBjMSxd5YrhqrwXl5NWhMe4N@qnoeygvPV/1sO1YvaOx10YhWlCXVbWZFaVW/EdlxLXVRuusVMtK1EsvVBK12fjFbhMNdSazNYyt2cTsqRqUFHw2Vq9nba9/NZbjuK/uy2ZoaqQ6ocL543hnErnxqUVgxZZF7TuR8@nQaXeSn@KbEckuR9UlMDiWLTd8wYeid1PX1vGeUbuu5Di@vknfX43H8rk7dzkqGqoeTl8VMiqmNQ/o5N6qU7hKSUozOs@dyIVXqrFpJs1CeysmL8iB/WdfzzQl/myoMGsvleJC8FGrlcYYSkvl6fdQbtHuLbsOoLUPXUX7U8xXOC5XnAfTjdqMYvmxl44NpPdK@yiuzWrPoW6m3nbKWq4zZQi05jTcTkQk1W1wmMw1TkbT8@XUqfjOVyoVMftDKsaog3D7zV@yYazSXoaSR0G@Ktzea4TObPTXaG2Yjy5vrLtO@M4zYhUTdLTrxUmas81f9hXlpJJpKWK3ehNgbsdKSY7OO9NytqaPMhLlq3a6Y3nxVXNRM3myM1Vg/ERufL4xnfXWlX1HJ7oiTW5WcWh7x8auutEowMVZpdnPiNd@9DIcyrcHFtVC8mA1WLWESHl08Ty94jjdqmW7vXI7PFppPjCRnZapZ6dwOEs/PoZ5Q6aakzLhVr5XMcJNjpt1GOfZc7hpGkW@VpGxUUqb5bPd8PMndLbmmsVhNm/GeLC5rejhUoBaV7nWbH6kDo2jc8aPVbfFOuZ6G47fVkZgw@2N2IrHlthhKVLS6L@@ryee9wTLengozHixD7aaksdnMaFSlquwkMcsuU4apnBtXlV7uMiNlMuVk@EYLJy7GufOLRV9qt9qViz6nRu96uUi82huEwv1spTCoRSeDRK2SiJZzVLO3vKmz/XxSYoecnBtdLqNaqhzOxpn2vH5xM2oOlYqcy3QWYjbCN9V5osOJSktYxRPMdcg3GqYulUwoWotTLTNvtsrFecSnXJWuw7Xlkr/tcdMIJz53DR/fXQ1X1bbAqfKw/Fxnm@1pOSeNRu14lm@GqtlGaLoy5pxWrlGpfE1h8@XFrDgfNjohQ8tfaMneotLP1WpCT@tHNLFXzSzE0KzTubu5aVWVye3N5KKe6FVXfW4Ua5tiPV5dmNQzmDztWblV7C3yoiGO6rNn5XwxvW0z0db5pNzqz3yj1F13FpFuq6FyJdsWuWnpZpAwW5WFdn0pizIzCVcHDDVv1VYrU8iohcr8ursQ26tVRsoaz@ziiuHK56X8relLFYqZfLXZ4HS5Wj0v5zPcZH49L98mfMKqcd2PSePnO6qmKHJYv2vIiWwoYoRbsfwqx4/OQ9Pz7KR52UyxGtu6aF9fX7FDmZ/wiW41H@9c851M5vJqeSly7VpNq121mlTVp9ze3TWZalMup8Ryqd5UY6WZft3pJLi5mrnhQqXopDcvL7Lz6@m0M0ld@rqmwEXUlSCw9blcZoQLkJ0kJUxntVylZizDz6vR82CWV2/bqYx2Hs/klmJ/JsxWoUx@5mOM4mLej0taMtzsLs7FLn89GFzVs8OINtOa8VyMukyJ10q7lxtep5bC1UW5XZyaQqPfi0o@I6SNmjeZltHil9I5Hx/OWkZXhs4narFmNpcy5Lt88kqXfKEkn6X4zjVXY8rD2G3lsq/Oc4vr9jIPU44kK9ZCMXWptKfJsXJxZWSvOs9XyeSg1bsYQ8HT4d2Ql1q@bL8n3Ihyhbq7vWqPC7Vpmxnd3F4naq0LX3IV0c@feXV4zqWWzVU1FBLE1GBWmi4iWplPnievqrx8uajUW6IwiDfCN/K5sqLySmIYyojsfDZXGN8ylk0WBmK2VVH0fIu/SAhqjWOYRefOrHZuk1fh89BNqDGZh8LG9ZwJiV1FWnYr3W64T2VnxpXWabCzgu/CzHQbozp/LjOVTr20UpflQthoZSo58Wo6X2rlpaRH7vjyeU6u8RILZkksPmjqrfEqO@tRHXFRzmWTibvwBUiQYcipeTfKCbyhDRYjpnw9vZAXo@m4rfsmC6buu@suYqlhe2gwfLncrJTmBT2mXhojhYrH@fBFR9cSRv15sizlzPyw3ZKjuVR70KtedJnrpniVusk17hJCrMaUnoVUpxEP8eVYh2fYujqZmTAi8YMxVV6G@jovCzqXmFafY4Xp1NdfzqamT7tLnF8lO4Nxjp3xnC@S6anP3KJ9KYekSkIYGNXOfHZb7ICFqLRnLYUq3rW0yJV0ITYu2tXrMVvL1Fcmk011@NvooKuzoiLO6hEzdlkSBglezBfuxqP8Rem5FOqKz6E5K@s3N5HiBUslRF/WVPsy077RbpRVmBMy3Wryet5f5SbDiihclMJ5vVuP9xtXnFyAYVR6Loe0dvG8fNfvyUNGVJVqox4KUXfxcKFzW39mZ/2b2qqpLi70wWWmJkduxZKi1m7bbP5GZyqJbPEmN6rf5ZbJeE2Xe0JzkGwqE995ROW5jFKOUwlhJmTbHaYlSBE2sVj1uLHAsHed8Th5wazixorJKMZ8lBysUr3zCdu5q6jnzeWYOZ8s7mrZW3Yq@Fi2xmvUjbmqxc7PO76r5XmrNJBbJZFnuMlyZFxkp8LlvHcTz/iSWqjpK/Tbw0W5NtA6BSbR6yXZRiTSiZrP/drSuKlQ7Xz5IpLIL82FWBhPK4vkhZaJN5aL1k00Or4bLarJRrweW7AzdVzIasVBjFFvjYSyaF4MilmhIF6LxvWqx0@o@GpaKRWTBV9M4Lq17l1ILDDPjb5sDgdi8@o20ogzfOyiWpvf3eUzzCQhjgol@RzGxDl3vVg2Rt1x76ZqRCRKrXZ9pfgqvmrc3VT6Sq1zeT3szQeJRE2/aI9S01VXq0t1n7ZqlXrqeb42kfOrWxC4eD0VG7XkQqsj3ebroSplxjuZOdjgbLYsLQdMKRa6EpXQ5WJynrqddOLj7ridm9W7i/Eo3kjE1KmwSpid59hUaCW6l5MGw/e686EvfE6pjdXytnAT1cuVuVY2a6pwFUqGy3fj1qQwbfkmuatiz8x1Qlov3CnPp75cDKyC5HU7Fa70rkbZ0vj8xri4CaeoZlFaTpOj8/i5rwaDyXRkVJNtOSzPmA4jt@czYTwJcZU819YXvVax3K/0w0lG80mJuXkVf77s1u44U4sqDGUs4/0557sogAWRl7qxhq9taqEJzEVCt7PIlTKIhA3lttHgzZyaGLciKSFa1NuK2l6oo3ZYujlPjOe8dDWissKqH5Vb9U6/sljN@6lxtM81Zq1M8VbpRHKKNlwYOhtPXYXb3HNtokeqplYrt/iscjPhOHHuW8jZ/LXemFH9QSXT7xSfp@KsHa1mopnlbT8Und7NRqyyui10w6NaLzMU5/VOdFWfR7L9c1apTyRtooeZULOtFMbJRetCuKIuVwVhOUzeZGvtaOtqlBpH5MG4UQstx1VJ5O/ujClb6g7KN2y/FGtnb1LjC9HICIlWSrwcMYtKr3oXz/WFaIjyDUsTJpwr85HLwq3PvOTl2LO0YivmKiUqy0pL6jUGs4xW7o9a00r2gsmy4dn5ojqJXNSZyJTLTpL5K72ry5RQiGUWrep13BjeZcx2VK2FZ0ntriYNbsP92pDjJ6F4EnTwdb93t2xl6tl5uVu5aBgZZbASfPr8SjkvFYtZhboQO5Vn45lTxWkm2qqWuzfPNxl90Iz1TKPELp4FZrlUqpc5nl92MyVjXGlfNpRSIjTpZ68TN8N@WWmpNSlyRfGpxPg2wSgN/nIaEqK1TLT43D7nn0uzeF0dKybfLNyxZqUOyq4Ua1W17nyyyg1D4iISLdwa1UFfu4PeOlpR4elFvduviyNlMa9fmu2ryKTBjttzeRxXOM0XLaSqVY4dRHASFrtVlYkqXw3M20ZldqUzzHAVnwrauXAlUeWwNsiU6vHLMHd@3s2nWuzkuSyEk9fRaWYertavfUpM0PKlwUQO5cb1kXAjwZShE6@NLkONitQa3E1zt6llg1p1e2JKuezM1avceJ4fz0bN1iIC06tmu2wYjfqt2S/Nwr3LhNyrDvvNfDF3w@c4zkhUlVyhOtam7d5kfhGNUaNi5HZ0nbiUBvFxoiQsu1dTLVW7XJVyw4uor6tcJs0uZ8rPVXn0XOmZZu85IbUbN5dMJ5vgldDzMmHeDjuMQV0kJ4XzqJBYlYZsoqVMZtNpv1pX1NKydnMNbE6EI83zHpPROjc1s92/EPjbixZY@peqUGrcXmqN89uL/rSvUHIExDfH6FfnZaN4mx/fsfNSfdmTWN@4ejWvxhIxMdXzzWKTynCaj8U6icllZVbMa3p8cQ1af1Bb1spCvXJNsZPrbmHsuxRZNqlfr9qzaD0j3MZ713NxHo3lMwtlmEy2Qouby3P@JtnTSvNJ65Id3DDzu9TYmHAtrp7hVbFKZZ@1yDK/MAuhWOEqfnF7I4zi835hGi5l5o1OKW6mKmKnE32e1@djoVJkxeZiNg/XitUbU4nGFu2bu/EVtEKM4geLm0JCuI4K/ZC0usvpRbWntLhMiLlkwvNW@8anDpTniuAb18LFiBYvhBY1DmbGd9npZT/ea43kznn2IjWk@lG@4Gsa8dJd/Pn2@VrSb0e@xARUTlKsz26uwSTpma1mdHEjprrsqp1LdrheccUWrphM9OJimiqFw5flVLlLGY3YBKTleR6@vczL4Ztauxmd@vKV/KI/bNy16rn5dfKuy05qncbsEidjESY0F6ujemtZKS5akhAvjOsFMUv5Sjdzo5rSxHq@XdCZWl8sRkfji/PiuTC94qeLguILDUqt5ex5OhGSl9cyJ@hKsW4OM3ykmxxHFnxJyzxftanlBVe4ZHPJdlIfS/zlqNIyRsaso4lSJvocW/jM@qgmXcXy9eatMmoNKxWdz12HE4aQHzcm8bvWaNGbCYX@JSWaqRkvL84rcVPJLovSbev65rLfCC35WvKyUtQXoR5TfG6EZibTSjZqzUGvokvlEQycvm5LVZMyqBRzqN5QnDYshebtzFU/OTBy56Fk@XJRbUkVX@imUB/lw8ZM9zHDSTWcX6mFy4g4TwzqN1eTkJ6b9Ye@q1qCuRtl1XmFipn9SIczxqm6yHa7bUYr1FeGcZ1s9XxXNzIj1MN3iezFim32Ilp/Ouwmu5Pz2XO3e/3cazcuoDlvfUK8cf1MDW6uLoyEmOLZfiubK2fUmRa61Cd1MTopq91WuCv6uot8af4cvgoVR6UeW6kMV6ssf6l3lGR@0rvOcctRK9mmIoVqqH8XEbTLVv65WxxOR3yuvOAjt@qF4buNVhbTcz2ZiLPR1IwzIu3JpO1LZmTJl4gMl8NwtjCL55m@Xu9Qhaov11FV6AX1uzhXYYxovyKbRivRbBRS9Vwxd1G@KtyK5VSjxN3e@ro3pVwh04xfXg3H0asua2SZ7PVw1AhTo3Ju3GdMMzmVGlLRKJzr@cXwbnwzmfbmiVnZ6K6UK24qDSasyGnjTllJxDM37edYNRQpXDOFu5WshBOxRYrq82L/kpHr49tOUipcMF15CBPoPMj/@PZ6qvOibgxTHaj59UpJ5FrVQVu/kIc1oFDuTTVenKSk8VCI3FF1ppEsJjrylchXu/VJotuTbpuXkYQ4XcD8tZtfXYl5Blq91W0Mp6HbeAFM12j0udQZTm5mlbZRj@XbzXItSrWf63mRLRXK5fad2Wcr1dCgODNbieRFgeUn2XGlsMz2sqV5kW91LnwjX7jZ52fFdkYutPucsVjehVIhPSOOqPgofp0V86w5j7VFPZq7HFYjnFxSF9XLpDap1y7D2cvCjaiO9VD2JuN84u1laiLFlgMxkzlvl7q5AZW5yeVH4bZo8HXFNy8RsGxR5v7wq48KEXRdIWDUTJX6NHmTrH3MxclXDp4gJ0/g4@07506gs8/2QQKi/Xw10ALl@F0tfEL42CqE7G0G8TBw3Fo8eb23GGCd4wTIBc/xoI/IAeDizkaoS8fMazI@SsrXCCA7nmQHBffByOPJPxjH8AUa/A5KYBN5os5DeOP9Jm2EI3jOBx7AF3o82dry9LDb1CCB0GScIgI//a4f8FSFHyEj2QIuVIvefdv6oZOd/ECcoSnkpBFXIOgiWe1TMRDTLgqrNTF@fTYDRQ5kcTbWvvJ6E45hk6F4ipzvQSt@0z@5Tz36j/i0ixZMiVMmxlSf98cDdTgTaZnWRr0Fv1w903QsSkegrPCPtA/LZONphpxcmYDfJJ0K2Uczkc8ncg4vnk9FjsXDU5TdNB1YH@/0kfaSgB9/jl0nb6SUPpo4Umgd8jG5jz@mlXToZHKvPJ4oPp/X9KVNH@vzYMSPrPdEm9qeiPfmI3lqnzmir51H6/Hwb/T9VUW6pir8UHUbNHnP4/YzJ@QULqcDTThtuz/NBN5U9e0YEeWJm@x0xLdRuEvMvcopqQ6cudQE3Lpbn0og4wtw8efDNB49eZuONfzwAY/QOLF9J7Yr8IXSpj1Z4o@pD4SfuAWOj9MfH9uHwvA0yu2HDyROsiItWmjJ8GDyiZPKq9rSzixZIE9OXU63UJ55cG/V6/8eSAeqBzL5hK9q0QHMArHYuwNOA2qyNeq1qMJwWVDW@6B4jo/3BE85oT86ac6JPwiPckPO3XkyaYmc0gOXU9oGJWdg0F77xAkSey/hQ2/EleDMbSV9GE0nGtl/Dlr02hzBt8s9aZykr3MGjSm@ndJDs8gMySEaWwADL3gW2owzhe2mcdoCHd/Iw1dYH8RXIy8TAIJ5TteXqBvx4QPE11dJng/W6ws9tKlajpUWGXZeUg2v3dTAODxX1q25j2niB3cCUWRL9GQrdQSpWNd3kieQPOHM4TvJQ8Q9Nd5L1iEZX2r4TrIEydYzkfvTVUi3dvrfATDRyxPE9clUn0xOkj3WgR54FMiLpbA9tM/nMHYtArTVMFZ77Oan7aNR6I9W61jCtiNe0D@JWFkAKNIeu/Pg/UZaSCoeu@ux5GKrTIsn9Bf6m4XZzpHA4idSEqhdLN97tIOf3iIA@h@oUvptulO41drriu7ITxCGnQG2NjArQv/yy9coswVxV/7YR0f6rBZCP9ytGlrc2uCx3rm2aVcr08rOtD@PfXTMtnZzfCQ29XA6ZXijQqy@tenXoqT0oQxA/HE7Gl2evPSnTcy98Ugfr7XHho9Wt/g2H8NvpAc9okiP9NO9TZD/fq5yKPeQk4MRubdRFnhOGHfyhp3GGjqwC30G0GtuvpIzfkdm7F76ayv7fbU5APpIpya8ObEULQ@m4ZlN4B7yOKtdt3WChezQfWzF47vkpF1k0jvIrPP0ngCBeQo04MjmqHFnTJSUoPVMKuj5UDjqJy7mFsjLhk2OsvoePv0zdC5knD1kT/H1Orsqid7Dmjfg63ojv85ed7lX1bM0/f7K3VsPNbs/uZFG@q08Ean7BKPkMR2i1wc3ndAv39ZD/zjOfNk03469Y3je1xVOozuS@D0i@PIOo78pZLtVCD/SOxyfkneua98cksghhPsHpY1r/ZMT47hdWn37XQsMqTrZTUeaLYROAhjK27n8ts11tlGd9umLT6Zj3Pg3Vhi@1c6SCjDZT6htdY7TuSIZvLdj10dHEY5sp@CT7Ghh6g5lkujYtmAGO/mC/BM2s8Vk5Cf06YGq9j2OwWQbDASDc0IHAPmt46zWZpVlXm6Kh@Jso5ce2Kd8OOPuCcR8tKPIuAIRaHzasolEHA1ItznBbrNl30gGeekiScfRCIpynj5AZ0VL@9DHr@MRem0CfdibydH4eCYZObnS1vNkJN5RD64cp6BjKDaHNbU@dWH8uiEQ5gwm2pvzLUkbvOxZZbDO8LRPt/yyPXWRTqQg2sTrRne8IL0na2pOT11YzFrgX/5w8JGZGjrTkxRGUGZgVPeW1AEtKNa7ho7xhdSBJDoK4/ukbW1C/LKJEyKICbQUlhZUhLnHfuc0niLq8lLWmXTEaZGl8ABf4jcuC7M@WP3WiS2aaizI7xImC6HgVDNVkmIXRM6uo3@RftmcpxoiTxHZMwabnFOCZwPjwecLrNil5SsZYC0DicXTib1bKO4xJ1G4rgeXC9sPCbX9Se8fKSMocPwQiUDZ@8WaTkFzEUl@oQyn6fGsNWQFPrwCQdk6ZUIjvqNYBLFOjCW5h@rjPYsBK4a4uKLc2/MUijgEY4qsqhoKObqCYv5TYIDF@A@NZr5Qrwft10xYHuvo5W75MeMjguTAOvt98bYbL3qr43GBVqN8wMoibqu89AY50b@ER1iszSbsCnNkp8UrPI/QqkGAJXdvqrGG91rghCXkcSf7zkBehuxTPTSwo5B3m2yerWwBJ5sDvMWKD9/kBsfzeBDEtTBRgeKcIMtAtMWLDxt2YBA54pTvW5dv3GOZj2virfTAm/TATnrQSreI2kAF@aG@ATreBnIdfNnAvdCuDZj/TVlpGipdqpDTpYKqvkX3yddgjSBM0qQN8Nm6KS2pXCec7iQEtlJ@2tP6VsrHnTxrAV@n31vptnyH7ZZfU7kD@3m3fLxSdgMJ5AwG@5HFV1IaVCT5k7X8uE4hGpbGY5Ws7NjeROysTmkviNjqJABqAl/ojt32LL3B4mMdjUP6jOvs9LMraC9JffK8JsN6P9KbjrWnj2xxiZTpI4xbkJEEyiHJH7dQEJwoaLTTc8@czEs783ILLUJ9dIqlnJNCdzs4VO11F0@jW/cv@ON09l3iHLiD/YkfLMoXVuWtJy12GUSU7kfXfjbtapP/v7irbU4bB8Kfz79CpZMcbh1I0vTaaa6ZOsaAZwBT2yRhrpkMASfxhECGlxDmLr/9bp@VZBtC097ch/sCtiztm95WK2l3NpnHMlEx9cIskuFerkPcPEi0xliB9m8wUqQ4Y3kf5Go8Hw1epeNEfqDQI8UzuadflKSzDHu6@X6vCvHxyfi7/Mao9e5IKxzGj8KGTt1jX/bGymWbWTydTakPxMTgREzn9/fDRPl1Ewu@ziH53Nt/j8sIGcSc0lAyPFwQlfktPKnLMVSoJHxAXuCeYfZhOr@@ltG9BcKH0tB6lRDIWcmwR0sZeBxu0PbllZdYzOHHFQPwkJZ9OSJkzcnek4ZoLxn6YpFk9Ur279GMVCBifMw@D@Fq9ZNhfJ0n/VunJvZ3dz/s7b7by4lMm6p3S@8OOH65VpH0h31EE3m/d2AYzvh@Ka82FvsmYB3sAKAlGpjoT6htxg8I72nYNGNwximp/tN48hAPSoYRxAO2AV/OWSJoyvNpLL0os59XpJBuBX/3iGs/tWTwemph@Mf8LH3X9tmxhmXgDtF9PLlLZvKm0fghGUCA@t7U1Xg4HC/YEI0rS1IeKHQXz0gob0yxShL7pVW0sO7C7mJJGj0Vhbx3OX5gP9JKDKSnJnC/zxeADDhRBIQ8MhnCOEcJ4esPe8kdmtMGAuBlKZOAJoBYG8z78Ys0GEzEv6RBh1cfjPtzeObt6Zop0@g35r5C3T2eJDT6ZgLmWuFiOdqpgqO6F4rQr0anduAKem4H/olXcSviuCuiuiscv93lSEyi7jdodAmF3apQaisKvONO5FNCwQ6pZIE/GHarK9yzduCGofAD4TXbDY@gEfjAbkWeG1rCazmNDk3WNUsQBNHyI9Hwml5E2SLfYqy6mJGVE35VNN3AqdOrfew1vKjLGKte1AKyKmGzRdsOIs/pNOxAtDtB2w9dAcaMihc6DdtrupUSwjm1fOGeuK1IhHW70Vhj1D9tuQGIX@Hy2CUq7eOGy5iYz4oXuE4EhrInh4RHBDYsEbZdx8ODe@YSO3bQtRTQ0P3aoUz0UVTspl0j5oziD6RC9eJ0ArcJokkSYec4jLyoE7mi5vsVlnXoBiee44aHwmj4IQusE7qWQGw8Rk0wSFr0nZ6PO6HHcvNaEc0ZnXbk@S2TKvmUBENU2lS0wgL2W5JbEpIfdAEVcuAKsMRp3aX0ADJladmQQkhSc6J8NkJIQozybIqWW2t4NbfluPjsA8ypF7omVZgXIgPBBN5Tm5B2mGvUE9ElH6mxGrrlWlydwqsKu3LigXKVm1pA6KnWwmJz6krm1JfLxsYttxc38J7v8ilTyMtO4h2/4pLGJ4OrFLL0Dk06H1c371a@0USTfqRXtQvKc9XFIL6cX18ko6sxluZpMbmDfTe9thAbyERkwm/GC6FR1UY5F3j9@uLixL6gdW54cWFaP1NyhYwflVBeWF/KZSoeh@PegJf5K7alvKCOtpWvd0s6Xs7bWrZT44MpyuVBrIrh8iIAazORCkpAwAYYGflWY28kcih5i3nVVsQRM9aNRXp7czyln9Ff2YucG3IJNDjLcwvlMtawTAYin4iUfkLCQUFUZBA@B5BcMcrSNI5vr4u7eXRY8isDlanLcN4ZLQOvi@YPil/G12vFd9bLM7G4a8rKinYHr920y7jveFMiE6peShPmrChNe/xnamoYESmFpkTFF1nV6ZPitiwO/6LSVmgepq7EORxI0z7zTrGY290/OFxLr6fpsm/h1jli29B89weXO@e/@rnMQB0swfKLRJIs5ZZquZwrQ1oZ65NpZviqv0GmRTKgORVT9U3M0zo85Et3wfnyNBlPksc89TQM1wK7edypVmnkBLUHH99/@O3QUB73J7MzS/53gQdRC1m6pEUvElLT@FOulzik91SfBcvJRfdB7SEjggDqSuNExL1PPWdKHUHG15BmILA7RYSBEYJsFBAkYFIQuJ8fvzJ0e93YM1UDKK6waoKbu94ja/g9UpW4DfSll8zhkmvtET@AnXZ/3cVThlQDUk0svrufLanl0uKCx71CVTsc4LUNXytGllJBt@P7nj6DJAWDMZO9MOAOPr@ptp2rRdJrUdHor1ztXJKIeLVOhQ7SwiGXCEV7PNU9WCYmlHKm2hs9dlVwIHxCqAd7FpIYq2nJHR28R9qcVcdQkM@PPlMVbW@nmH4XMKSaiihp/18NHZPvDUyKPNAg1gDrk0epnNMvbIT@8qsp/pQtFV69AedQtVj1Ti13EzsKyqF2ia7edQQZIWFlAWU4aZHiMHSWrs6SinNFTP9JHgz/f5TJBvi/04KToGfS4nE4Gc3jn5QkQ5WyotUrCyVZ6BNjuWNqmTTzSd0MzFO@Ym5SxtQxvEe5sUQiULWz1AldGVKsuEEAaOSwa@T7Lxz4cie@6dHK6Qv33V/kTv9k1L@7L@qAXHqqeAb33GKdy9JH5PBiyi38XZFD10B8lS/s55HHDCy4aBS7XIqtaUHCeLvHYw6YLr9ho0fay7lpQgx7uodnzWlXdS3d@R/VCaNslhnor0@kin4/2Fe6HYKYQisDvt4B0QMIn33KM6zERjiPQOhGvuHpha38Qs3iMYbNKzkvi4jdc0x7V7xmxlSkfGnAaQdQAs7WQMVsuoxnC0wXQwmdfYhk0ERxi92YAImyRaZqhB58zRJJnSfZRUo9mynRXlPqO6PbEeLfxtLEpXOUViJA5V2wlkSzx8Gghj/HdyFD/hZiPVrF743Yr0pf7lfCNMcrd8KClf7WNJMIaZwLaJc0D2VS6vVvkVjQbTRZ7CSP9Me4dhTnOqYRrRk4Yt0mpf/puwsCtJW1M7Ci8G2UGpE@yYns85ZWX/Ak@2761MWTsjN/JqaIOErBgVmlBoFk6E04pPm8tzF9/wA)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)

### Explanation

We’ve been chasing Haskell in polyglot chat for quite some time. It has long seemed an attractive option because it supports literate programming natively. [Literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) is sort of a philosophy that says a program should primarily be written for the benefit of the person reading the code. In Haskell this means that instead of comment blocks, you’d have non-comment blocks. Sound’s attractive right?

Well, not so much.

Haskell seemed to interpret the first line of the polyglot as the same preprocessor directive we’ve all come to love, but then failed on line 2. This seemed like a blocking issue for a long time, until I started looking into Haskell’s option to use C-style preprocessor directive.

Much like FORTRAN, Haskell’s C-preprocessor allowed c-style block comments (`/*bla*/`), which vastly simplified the insertion process.

Haskell, unlike the other members of the `/*` comment family only seemed to read start and end comment declarations on lines that start with `#`. This was a difference that could be leveraged easily enough, so I went back to my documentation in the FORTRAN answer to figure out which languages were commented where.

The insertion point I choose was immediately after the C family languages, where a `//*/` was purported to take all the related languages out of their comment state. A careful read of the polyglot up to this point told me that Haskell had still never dropped out of its pre-processor comment, so a `#1"" /*/` statement is read by all the languages, and accepted because it is essentially the same directive used on line 1, and the `/*/` is a toggle to initiate a comment for everything not in a comment, and to close the comment for the only one left open: Haskell.

So now we have a private place to put our Haskell print statement: `>main=putStr"128"`. The `>` here is the Bird style literate programming I mentioned earlier to indicate this is code and not comment. Everything else on this line is just a modification of Tio’s “Hello, World!” example.

After this line I wanted to flip all the comments to the state they were in prior to editing. A simple `#/*/` would do this, but Haskell protested because of the way the polyglot ends. On the last line with code, we use `*///` to end the block comment and initiate a line comment to hide the remainder of the code, but Haskell didn’t accept `//` as a preprocessor comment indicator, and concatenated the before and after of this block as `#//`, which it declared an error worthy invalid preprocessor declaration. Haskell allows junk code after a valid preprocessor declaration however, so we just needed to change `#/*/` to the gold standard directive of `#1"" /*/`.

### Transcript

Ok, now we’ve hidden all the invalid preprocessor directives from Haskell’s pre-parser (Is that a thing? That must be a thing.) But we still had the main parser to deal with. Almost everything is hidden by our commitment to literacy, but Transcript also uses Bird style code declarations, so it had to be dealt with. Fortunately, Transcript didn’t have a problem with being encased in a Haskell comment block. So, with a couple adjustments for Perl and Incident, this:

```
You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
```

Became this:

```
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o<
>-}
```

I should also note here that Haskell comments don’t like to touch Haskell code. You need a buffer line between. So, I’m adjusting for that and Retina her as well.

### S.I.L.O.S.

Finally, within the Haskell private code block, I had to add a `<` preceding the `>` code indicator to balance the symbols for Perl6 and the Flaks. Attempting to put a lone `<` on the line above worked for everything except S.I.L.O.S.. It saw this as something it should parse, and then crash about. The simple fix was to make the statement into this S.I.L.O.S. parse-able statement: `1<2`. So, in total, the main Haskell section is now this:

```
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
```

Comment: I think what happens is that the "literate pre-processor" runs first, stripping away everything except lines starting with `#` or `>` (or in LaTeX-style `\begin{code}` blocks), and that happens before it gets sent to CPP. This would explain why CPP is not parsed on other lines, and also means it could be put on `>` lines if you want. Also it means you've hidden things from the final normal Haskell parser, not a pre-parser.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Testing confirms your thinking. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: This is impressive. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: `runhaskell` can accept options for particular phases, [`-optL`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) passes the option to literate pre-processor (unlit).
Unfort-ly, there is curr-ly no way to config unlit to remove lines starting with `#`, which can be considered a bug 'cause it must remove them according to [docs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). [unlit.c](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/utils/unlit/unlit.c) already has necessary var `leavecpp` which is set to 1 by default, but there is no command line option to change it.

Comment: Oh one more thing: Unless you have a reason to avoid it, `main=print 128` is shorter. (Variations might use `print$128` or `2^7`.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Might not be the reason why but the loops cancel thesmselves in Alphuck with putStr.

Answer (score 11):

## 155. Simula (cim), 7000 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# do           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxx8=,
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n114O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p seLz
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1Zc/PKkiD2fDD@B37BR@kckuICgDslUd/HVaJEkRRXUcvRAUGABAkCFACuOjrRbTvu9DJhz9zp6bjTPdP33vY43BGeh46xHTET3RGO8LxO9I84/djh8P0H15kFcJMofd@5PYZEoFCVlZWVlZWVtaLNG73f/nYPL7qsKfOuopm0KRom3dHliaj76dSc/sTLRjgQpCiESurd8VBUTeOQ2qM5mpZVQe7AO21qA1GVF6IO/gGaHulaV@eHtNnjTVo0BH4kGrQ2Nkdjk9ak3dGCNJ0dan3ZhzGHstoFMFPUR7pokvAQTddVhR@2O/yLkPCLBEc6hBt0RlS@H35v0oI2HPJqxwDICE1nSqlsIfkCQ5SmLzXdEBGPIBqGhp4xmp5lReEFaBxAeV3WCsni6YsgjqVPgXR@pIgzmm8bps4LpqypGMTR1WK9Wn4ZI0A3arncS98gfeHTVDo3FgZbQaQMyrrWGQvIH7MnQjDyVJIV0aAEyPsJPbJL0o8Oeo/WRb5jgVGSptMYhR4OFFqmhdGIbit8zy/QigywOTZGi1gE9ALClZ5Bz0ZD2pCHgMXQhuImLQatimKHNkaiIEuyQCigxZkpqgbk2PDTMtA@lRWF7ogKRFiTJXgBGT02NrwsIvxUR6NouITRi0ys3vZFgFHFJSPEEZQEMkLDggOuLPkx1fnRCIgEZlaBcFMegvzJptOgRd6QUcIhiiGqHcLD0Ur2NZpXN3NJT2Se5oHesU5wG6KOBeoneOmeqIuAkl9Jn2uqyyawAFmcpMsir9M1XRTd2/VgK0lITMMUTMyInxTh8bEzW8o5oSitGH5@ZFJ7erB2dU7xtD9B7z8cwS/hcBxR2WKGftq/Q7cl9lDcI93Fu@nED7TB3N2J8JtxbaarP1OAlQKuKDSjjUyG942AQJ8JBDI8OtHlmwT8I2UjYfr4RVlsCJgF1YHSoPMq3fCSnAljXceqvWYqP4BMK5raBX5CZvWxivxQ6QgLRSBoUDO9tDgBroHIkzLSpoTDtZ4MhWZgkWxUJktBEYaCigLZszm6TNfQlDGBg5iGiQIIXIGoiDEv0Q1a4mUFo0A4orKo1kVjrJgYZ6x2sORBAYkdP70kQ9A6CDTUJpAcD0iJB9Sn4UYtJEQBMBSERrKKQT/@8z/vdLuAJykImt6xxbVBdzSBqFKeEAv6iUaB1VReIWQBnBdTt6JDAhNekTu8icmrczsJQgRJdaqNlQ6tQYL6VIaq1eMnUB0lSRRM0RJyS/t66SE/sHSHbEkuZHzIt6FgSQIkbZJtH/0pDaUkiNQekRnfcGxKMdo3ytJOg/nW9fHQ9fHDnQjEuf3ug32G6R6BwPkPiBe8Od@TnEZySzsaJm9ococazc2epgZon0A7hIQ2ElWXcwuH0@vU2063H3Way30kJwS/JKsdl/MYZPEEEna6j4SEcCsf3h@9iL6ZJKCZIhqsrqJLcDsoUDmkUkyYIS@r/tGcbvhs10aYZjwgyzHYv@GNjHnpN7E89kjrg3KpoYCAHvIbiiiOXKyfc6OaQLid@caAXTl9gcPO8KF873HuOT2bWScYIKdbGcXKWpM1VFvKqIcNDDBFNUagvnWUXYEH6TFQi5tgAnjpNpFrovpBsxCdOBWduki3QZEu5YhUSavKYXwfKkobw7oKLeG2a7TY2ajQoAygTpvGK62saFNImNCGbRioEBUT57tQRBDZylDSypCVIvHZztpABcWC2NoiHfO1ZagMWO1At9uyv5FHAA8GLBjAZlWWDR005OeARbDaxHXFoWUJ6tQQ1IQ@pwURdQ8oIdFqWDCRMamHBhg/aAaxvkA4vF3XXlU1U2eSvhtQ1gvm3RqFmd@sVKhwaEmc0gqvdsd8F@0vFaLwgiCOTFthQU4ME1TSy3aHePrsRtRv9Kj9Ty/TJo2J3bxupIHK3io9u0nkUcvYFphPAaVK87YNSXdkHdSTMn@ZOgBMXiTu@A5Btgj4zvEGCUtLAIRMnInC2ATtBoI87clCD2QXqVMt/Wg1Ri@TB6/N1EHD@6RV0kgMd/JNgPIzKy8k400UPizR13igkUVUJ1sepPA3Pd7HzBvDHYi1FYnQIGz4@hneD7L3GZxDTdV2IAVGrtAiyHaIVQ5gkVXRGoQGbGl@kcq6MhFXRQRlBtoDaj7IX880R8YhtBey2Ru3/SApTE2f582SisLCmPpcNjXL3Va0NqhnA@ons0yBEcZtefYiQ8RvVYZ9g5qAISYZdAJa8McxSJ3LKRmgOIl/GoE3ghxEgRMU1t0BgATID4xySQZRyTlQKtW5KrgcflKV/FDpHF7agRXX4QYHxlrxJa0NUQvRTWIgoMWX0kFzSaCtbN1PVD@/s8lbtQHEvnM6/X1NVl1Pzg8fPjgPnSeg4T98@AiuY3R9RJcHXB@Jy0dcCOdHF4nhJS4MvSUx0O/e@Xy7xDxz32OxzbB1WsgjF397eBi89/K3nP0M4NMNqg40G0D78AF4nO5EAp1ut@NkChn1t6Xt3KdRO1cFXR7ZTDjnJ7z1bnMhSNggD0eajobsETa27/NkmNChNQTjVei5dOfdLXt3f/d01/HcPTu9GNt9xCfakClIzzX0d3VtDM2m@zZ06OPu3e7bIDSW7YSTdR64XDGfAgnxbvfXMbeHt7jtcoqgtV13d05gqs2fW6GnE3wzb8DtXrEK6MAGGmxDl9P/FIP02@57t8cJcd1OL3Q1Ek4ncEZAJhgk0yiZhEE5EMB0tbDV1RsOQD3SgqGgTeHTLbMCXpkDy7NDHivT6ZDOk5ZVhfYSSIDmsrPq4qia6lPHxBAmVqq2mRDpjCEE8cPGAxWjvAWDiCV5BpY@VNz50qLBBhiNmjR09zRF9DeJjeGgQfJprK/@nWZN2WoX/IKxLkQwYMA5UngBauY2ujsHfQcIQVAZZneI@@gV4pc2D@mefC6P0DIIvIr868jE/B7LRg/ZCyYS9gl0CbiKtjc07iLhWp4WoNHuAqfFmWxaxjgIQhWjnPGGy43mX9Iyn9BqwyYfiVp23Ul7rAnQcRGh6cdQqxdIZ9WJrGsqMtmfBdQgsUdYBi@Q72IviFEymQ9k3ubvLuTAsVfe3AZvN7G@ZK5gCDSjaorW1egDAEDR9PttwYbKUeuNRUoUehrtuIMmJHBCMx1xwqBAOkBX98AW8oG9IeqktV1FswdvKFMbQ7PdERV5KJt5MoqhqNg2rfXuMjQNBbBGUJZFk7INynVzhQMaa1Widi347Aw1jkGJ5EkXS5nsQzlZO0s4mLGhM4rchhx2xIchWBaKaDhoeo@uiBDbjrAYKBVNMxOkkuLYyetrD4GW8IXMQyGfqiQrLSsZEs@Qh2OFx8Qs@Cp5twjMbw68SLo2XFlRhs3b/SByU9waQMOuhR0awtCxPXy24R9F/yEOffkFqisItE@zXleeNmAMAXE4zC@MRlTX40FIMjy28rQh4wQlDpH59fbS84ljn9F/NT62YatuYtwV/nakFXKOIDfUsTHayNwTFyD@E1OSUNmuvIPEe@ADNGBlEQ7vGBa0wSMI29HaojKLhHyiIvnN2cKPBkwkRFkP2td5C2JHXGq22BWBMsEa8c2kFwG8TlkU1kBlFDRQDwXZIKOom0JBrdqhO8qxbEy32kzHOiSw7tzSvsnuXrljExGRT5CogYY23Nr1AD3QMGJZoRgOlNcxJdCk5LYF@oqo1yFWvRi2JXLbAXBod/SgkuOwI3LlHAetsK@pQbsmTgkYMVkJMuCWrPJMhTzQeN1Fz7YZvkVMW5TGoPIZsCnQ/RkwXzxGIKV2W34LFPiCpC@fO8D0cXsX20C@eq96avQW482xbipix37@l9/rQAG8Lp4ePyfN3MrxAHwjsiG9WVp2VHwht90lS2D6Y0XmCRuI63MoBR4HyXhl5diNGvUx7fP1eB0Kd74sXBBOvEFlf0fOLMp1URl3xOVzdyKExdv9QSu2Kg9JjuCJ5hAxb9@I/qI3a8UnBoWi8R2CxWr2ZXFd2la5iDO@C5ljNpQSqNQvoHPZ6aTXo73QuzLH1h0HeD9XrvIIf7u5crgtZGyYb3Mioxl8W36Dj0hG5C3JtioM9od8ksIPLOcDOndn1sqOLne70A@0n2@BQaffFI0RGD7MlDzeEYtl60GTVp5/D6euWPe3QJbzWyvHW4CQVYXcforwEXEQoIag7OA0i2@DTfILxip8e449md5PlyJMkDTLoGQSgsfDBrGFXg3LrSd0RqO346NJQeLH47tjW3M/BIGgSZIofq7mQusjD3nFF@hsON9UxMt@9tq1A7QPHVEwoxXeACExbTaLEygWcntPcLFBEVBc1q53xHZNznL09a0BvHWckSxoimyMSHEvX97SiC@HPtZocIaP3NZR8e01fzvQacDG2rdy7a7UmmDiINobcvQFSsoav8IRwg3B8Gtv8U7Qpvh700zoaRPRuu9uuBY7qfoCFeRTiGTIwo7oHeFz4orTMeS2m4uDnVSZgrLT/5C@1DS9J6oGHfCzyw4/joFDp98aUKvlS2/LtCErmgE9C7y/xwvoQRiGdd8tzZtsk3nVR4Y1Nt27o@0kijRydJLc3yhcXulqSiTWZXi4vSkBY11CTW8/v1TDrTQUx31WQ62MHk3l7Oebqn0A/58TDjKUouOY6YbzHVtqlzqzx9reziB0DXAiZHfmcmyMxPQzVrfvrQLQhd6Uny@fv0Pr8RZ3l63HaE5MZrDpMEI8Bg5Tt8zo3yW10Pupdb5MR71CG/1cJjYKd6CIoLHJ/VWR0gGW@4kxOJb9co0lKWNxLO7UIKV2X8R1Je/oji8nirWzsW8PgTDAPBwAWUEt7A7hF1GN7Tm@vatweEWGSv5Za2anqhmBnT3CPnQZHGV0vI7YVcejrcLd4F1lrFbe51xvtKzZWmeLSAz5qRop9nmbacsUN0Tye8tszw416PZqQ7Ah1C8ofxspGVOy7luIic8ac1/G8Tf9XbyH9GpyBexXsEegVOWB4cNBvC9TPIG3@usEOB6HHpkqmnO8v8XtXYq0rWnKTykd0KcdGc00MD5xFdXnSumV7WPPs9HrkQkDRzna0ltjElZbY3cegXvYUX6zoMuQJZM0Dl9Syq8GDd9ptTaGED/Xh4QWmwz8GLqwdL9FbwUrN@eP@aPvErwcGGOWjveQxf3BL7GPRkujlwwh47CzNdC8nhjYe6F/RnPglNzxGUJPHIrk9R2Ln@/0x8by8SbQTMPfjmA/Q8ZY34g3kqHCq3jfGtTeMIlMTRUNxuT1roh9FUXkwRq1fN9Sssuh253MzQ/5rpj7rGSthx1wBQaZ7dpw7h6AOLQmRQWI9hk1YnUDNXUgzo3lc7exPBegPMfDd7HtquQCjm5@tlb7mZ3D1Z@x@dSe1lN7Yk8nNWP19lbdAIk0rRWl72UC6O/xxgCXnBCFtO7j9YxN7iqaonwJd1EhWupR03YPvGZxrWcHov4kvHO@DQH247NjdNBuEyaRBvytutMTx9A8GZqpjUQfeXsLVMERHuu@eyw5X3IadFMW9Y413YZDe7wptxWRnspAQt/YnCDYPXrUVjQeVzW9Y8EDZ5bPLxmPEjT9c01Cl9fM0Yg8HkbK2CA3MoTrk3aPTR7SOULol8iCbFoTnZbEil2tLfTkzxVeW@RNVR4wdu23X3dL@bYuJhmXaV8Gvf2KDKzS536UgcRmeBUf@d31Xi7Y68TfNUbSY12ff143bE9RroZTrUkAdLw1GGPPO@0IJs0@zuYvZ63fmYmwp6neFChiSKPR7BNZsEy4N4eGtlYe2CxQgkHzM1wSNGHwWVvizcFKe1YTWSXIG3Ov4I8RramtClkSvFo0ZnjttczgJ@v2ylVjtTx8L68KukiWkC2XFNF7uLBtjEmZmu6nCZzLxXs8bjdlRcIRnK4KYEsoskAXF@1Za38NWpENk8DKEn17S@8/zQ7ZQ@6ZTtCOQwd9f29hJcvHsrMRWVlbsaLe7vP3iX2nz@fcd96phzTrJKCiAh3qnaD8Fpwkk4dF5zrrtMpbiwbQvczpkbUY0eiRBb9QLTtQvetgEZIi1nRrSZ21brOG0z7/@a869jpoMAEMeigb0IHqqrh2XxuKPW360UrXTj05GvG4jhpxTHuoOzB1XzpJG1PUA9byZ21K13O1mL2Y0t5hAC9lFNgNKqxCRWMUV1KYVqFZ1HQ00ZInO@FVrGWmBE0ZD1VQvB2zZ/jpqkwWSYz19dQ3uBBMNXVsfTpeOk93RBxwJ2tfiMGlaNqArEJDSv7zX1lLSMkKGBAhdC@TJ0vIN1LEhS4cWbcpCNoYqF4iWYi6ZoO4kMnQ6I@xLwO1QbT83bguhKxtBUn0LVd2YjLW6s50skr7srQTt0DgerEjWXLtJyunjVv2PvEDPWTE//J7jPvJ5pvja180Yji89BLk6BnlajM4DMHrUCft2J857GzhYnuytnwlVPYuHBe6SXEtV2oOyTp9InfilKzUJKsnVLRpcAG8akD9gFc3QW1VmsS@a2wZzr6qSYdxnwjYojy4rJX9ZN0LrjrEKPsz@nu6h7LiE2guzMKbxRAFF7oOE6nlpGlwc2qbyYjtMZnjmQT8gWCCZGf/IXF8Qly62NFw4fntt3ezAOu7m0Wz94yxZM7d3exrNnAN3NOgTd//hsEKlC1mnvb9J@z33xv8nHY4np1H1lQ/1PL9p3K@nK3WkrV6Fbj5bGV2L6fpQ36tKVAWyHKanqaQFf3AFl0Wjc9rj5UGWb0BuMtF7/P0Me4fcrupzVUjBNRmtcPn2LecKxAwbjdjfyb6rviGuBH@GsDWTJJM21qULhNBsmXGaWxqUO9StrBcsLqDCbLiCK672KEKCY8cdAK45AMufSGP6Ne5tErwI/GAYvw8o97HsQsF8GoN8RoAmbRKC/NrhVuZ25n55/8KOR5Bu/aPzTHB8W6OEeK9HAPgOhqJkUvmC/VKdjsSiNN6@xZ0IHTcySeRumVtBLGkS7P3HCw1E7G9DXtt8Uq3GvRENohtjvImYcsA3VtSHclUr4HaxVqJSCcVAzR5pwOqqT03UbOBSveTFT7WMh@fSjv2gFn@VUPrpR0UwhqJ12vPQXNNBdBi31mR9wkcwWxQOzbL3InMj//8z60NMncmuP/Qds/YFLz9sf0mgfufLUM4Dt7@xeotAG8/t96@ZZCVr3cDWLlZMREZ2MiXaYN0H5BFQ362kXts27DtlFUwYOUh8HpCWIfgVrbWnFnjcd02gPNQXMB2VNKol0l6on7vwrXchwyDpggO@PjJYhJxZnUeyNLuxzFubYKmhImEIyEOrGfRN1kiJMszu7h6wULodh@CVFITeZT4ri3Qx8fHtMMQeEVMRI4sljP7/LdBx3crQvcBlrKsllsa4kCUdQwIO7GjufZ5D@fGqFg5nZyTvj8Cg8QqQWjTXMQBIG70VpfrF6HR1GxWgXio4swkin@@tMbAFFLJ8jnR2uC2ROQDRBZu3IDzUsrXaxRw@daG3Ps3i8HRRLAqgh06dgnZ7bf0nXmn3tsbsWgQmF/tEDkV3H@0Y3fWSnqSr7cFuV5u6sHc0J@qqobrVnJALe0KMIEgw0XcG3XKYaMCerEGfQ8ooc5AHRREua@NjGQ6mz8vlauvtrUQSOdLMCftPDn23Pn83tv7lcP5QuqXTE3lmOplKrdk5SZV66FfhFiP/74kc1dqLyl9I/WmtTjkddok4FVCHPuliMlYiy9HpkheY1@HMhuAaWvy@lWqLvfT8@398cmduvcq@e93bfnb8x@gcIHrziAb/pz0Dp2TXy55qeHebsO/XEYZcKw3tK6Wmlrva@@3N6asdoqvd6csF9dQZFnxalUx5X9j2Q3k3c9YSZGtGRZhS3pB1yxJ5ZDUdYIC9Wr4fpMa2s7L603t9urZFZNKVkeW7LzjVejD6LJgQRtEQVvdXbJNDDo8eXPdR4J@F3bASVdwTro9oCpWSwE6Mhl45PXlytdVSFUcyr7akh5UHOvdJvY2ix7kTZHbR3zidkavVpG@t@nCb4wU2XThDpCZH7uTkBuXGzPAHeMWipn7OH5v71ahl5tKPGRfSnkM/CprI3rdhc@IS1cFenF0ZgzIQQxE@nw8BDiJPCoithIiXdR8EBn46FwScYs7Mew8@IedMKTu74mzjtyFlsbl9oJK@prj1jtaeNySoTpBD1usOsU1DpuM@Um7cDY4xt/yflntiDMXLpA/vEfugL9z2pw43Y5XMkC2Atk7Yzov9wQtlQVv2rV2vZ/mhUKIx1eKYLvuxOP@nkHhKl/ogUCKVVMvgBPaUJc05Ee0a0w2VRm0nyavrjuX6jVM3U37TrA9m9Iq7fGQvgs8SICfJjEl4pIVHDt04V5kF5OAckZfQ@3gYyGP6FvO778HN0nETe/j6EMazA3st7spME0hyiFBCw0w/B0iRVPopSFF1nOfJEuRbREAtTOYVORuj1RA4AXJNX3yzXqPwUYNtLgajx/apbGtDuM0iMXxDo0BaHeouaVtCvy112kC11CJAVQaOqUyKJRPF6KqQn11gcwMoXbS/BiETHd7l4dqeNd7rEkKexaJZ/bCTyB0e@911vmkaGDP7DNHpAd89Azt/nd32PBLdtM/Z/5bxs8cPbn2lcScAWPMfeLa7yU4T/DA49lXD1z7Kpoj33yDHefnfbB2HvwOv2MGQL59xX0E8gzWUWJfPdrnj137nUTggMSAV4/H/QQRfjAY/9M@/8zsfwPWhBd8dKt2uvYNsh2K9fu5Z6APa8g@4wWZecJtQeRIDEx@X/Z4kAb//gMS8ANzV/WQduWuypA@@pFt5DLd4VKNbNsqq5J4dcSHxUDb@3Cl0cNkDb81t/ewBN7ceb0jbJd99Nvf7nER6G59jARdmudjmD3yOMPckXOP3vvkYA4cuuPpLuOb0KLPeSvxYf/jfXlQLl@771x0nHbupUsOLuT4lo4HDhhqjzlgv48yzHfffQd2KH174j/x37tvfc77W5fVk4rSJ9HogTcSO/B@cj6su25R2u0KBNzArTs6TN9Fef7AEwp8Uo8gJI5XkObAifcY/Dg6HKazeP3d//F3v/i7PyF/vyC/v5FleWR0OvDTevSAXsA1kGj8J@5FZ8PNo7stLVxg4IPdl0CZ/Aourux0hoPO6re46fDjB/gj/3CtXvH@gfjY3gTk9fWBpvZOhL3FHsdxe3Py94BubrZx@WbvXgzHBe6@wgNlIh8@fQWcFT3kOjz8tGYh44jGHJpGfHqQQpjW9rAHsL5mPryoveX@fV6q8fhH19r4VzHxrzFoDHyNQUXAv9QA/y7b@FdYFBabRMUSXmrvh0TC8@5F7/Dz@x@WLmrvu@PvEv@IC7NF7UGvaO/k5P752eO79X/rOTqy/0GfHK3e8LJcQMC9x@c5vj0@9p@czE589ye31N4TtTd7pvYCDhD7uwNqLzE7rhAqbzMny9xsXQXwOfbd35YLYNDXvIFj314gl0x7A9V6ao@Dt/D6FQOD@FrJJjOlOkCXC9lkNXuab2TrZfA37h9OPn3y@KGEPgF/Tu6BotnXnhNPwjRN@ubhwE9/wfWww2W9UnuZk1md8R0D0QVqr0JS8vkfTu6/p/Zu925dno@ej6zCTlhuwA0utdL6v1SaQYA8Y/uazvbYHtcB8aVZsc7O2fmMHWolrgNOEf7YIThlVpqxXVZlVY4LlSKlT1vY3v4flrTLkgb4NIhrzlgTUbMSPLul0iVglCD1PvzJLMvOgMwZO4F/VuHI9e0DCxl1s3d31C3t@E4ELeTnnH7W6Y84nfJ9ODJ6fHoORB5vibUSjt/f4ibHewftdT7c3YKOcd4f7THG3R1jqWhHIOQ4Ihshn58fHjLJWvLhgcFxntnxvueTx/cJrsSJ59h@fNzrnBx9vDv0oXRbEu5/2GOOP96dBH3ojniA4QHwO2Y8P/Fao4TnhzvK6Zo2m038NaeTqeUiDsvvrrkKxVuTAS/LhV5wISizK/62Y/ZawFyu2/D907Pb7b5zHjntLcUumuwpdnB3s4BEBxxuYvvHoeHkgmieRcLuk5NIGN4jMbfPxZJgK8qdYzQa3Tn8ZCzBT9a2JRJJXefnBCgEbfedg9cf7hy3gftEIh4m3mFfPEJrui8edDvc7m@542M7jYAbvB3OmUPTnfTT8@af6@n52EUuN/653ehp30/cLgh2h@Ft9uSij13HLvQDL4z19HyCTgL3BK5bl/ve/fxs@cHd5T62cJ64gW04YPJf8V8zaGMEDe3zHtpcKh0Ku13tuegORVwxT9z@S3yADLgcQWcQ8uVw8s7b208HwYNo6Pbj/YH/AH@u47uT@x1tixtaeqgxSwFPcHvIPmrPf1RxcAGHEwX@SLD3KStalw7Gj7BJPqL2IJoDrj2QRxqYdnK8EpJ1k@M@gSr5RBOu0e572v38BIJjBYJN5rKnNe7uZizWXtpNH7UT@097/PMRwU8/O5bgtvwR/C7nEZn3cjw59nn9lrt3PDv2n9rPaLwecG5iI4VDR0cHIcsdjYGbO3BbQ7lg5Byt3BAiGrxwhBX9aA/lwwlMdEOuEm2xK6tgsG5WAE84HP7ABOAx@zqSDcwO7OvkYMcVC8Q8B55Ptwdgx2NR3BPf7z9QRzipZM1gOXwOqxrRsTghYo82jDgNCu1Y3C97Zsu/g8yB5eLwl/1gUNDvaoOITOkoCw29ght8NEn6YPlDB5JuiyLY8KKiLDe2QzdD6UyhT/@B2kOrCkw4Q4RrWObFsShOx@OpuLrSsnHI9/v8iFw//upnP/7qf/jx1z//8dc/@/HXv/jNL3/xM/j9Ffx@bj1//u/jYbz/5pf/4n/58S9@DZ5/A7//BL//@Jtf/uvfs37k/W/h939t@P2t/duAs34U4Prj3/zyT/7yN7/8Z38Gv39r//7s5e/HP/0P1v//bf@h89c//unf4s1@@dnPqX/461/h/5/89T/8p1/h///6P//DX/@rf/jjf0ccf245/p9/@@@t@9///s/@/r/7l3//@7984/6zd@@//AL/X/7/4PPldH4Jni/J10/1@eXvRM8/hhvrVECgfvFHP/7rPwA5/VN0/1Nwwz/t8VmXxwb4Q/T8fp9lwc65@34T8nuGA@ODZjY8/5D@/g5XjXNrSMD/b75nWDCSWAtyhXMT8o9@88t/@Zfg@/0nGvxsyD9YRrf1zRbkik604620/hCA/2ID5g9//NXv/fiX//2Pv/rzH3/1xxRH45mWH@gPVIDGJ97QkziIa3ZAhYOg1pZubu0Ohog7DPddtibOGX78tOVl4T7YBUwAP5LwDztNV0zjYEnbrsQ@LOPvxPCR/gTB0ASRVugY7/gCPinoJNh9hcRJjE5QXjqWgM5zCgET8E7C0UneocHCczITVGYJQdMZ4Ae2ZrMZ9Da@o79b@p9YoPQJRf9AoG00CQvRDxR42vF/IGgTGGc2owg2/LdNLHTjbxmwvJFXyvaYWcCzVx4UZMhLolNRul6GWyV/elbbeNayyfQZFaFTpWLmxSNsA4XpQjZXW71GrdBl1PAKRStbKLx8tR8t7fAw8QMXilLwhLcxnj@CLQyeXDUjh0v6j49B1G/Z@6dQNBAKh8KBYCQSjga4UCQeioRjQZZjI2w4EODioVA8Fo8@03GKOnnyHR9TJ9VsDdDUSjQXYP3UyTU989Pl8pXvmTrBYcGE1YwCqiefYVAUtrEf6HDU6/X7/XDDp5dc5Onf/3YJwr3dudpzcCwXdjgibCDqcEBD6vvomIt0jx7SQfpoBLkrLKhLnCCLc9bKJhmRgksX47iWA5rmqUqW0rTxsLTx6G1PeKAXOnW52zNpc6qtAAzDAMt9ZdMv7fmVXd@k2zyPv596QQri5mW@72FaaRC/VyHKa3DqDCyUIR55ggtQTRwmkiWapfxYVoFAPBaOxYOBmDcWj4XCXCQc9nIBLxeNReOsF1gf4yKxMLDWGwvFgyGQCS@UfjgepfZEtSNLDAM9dQ667PiUVQF3vh/jEQKav3dC7XVECZf90DNXx03vdVYe4xjtCMbuWBoiOrgIhVPwB7MEdPlwcUKQozkH5eBpgd7L5dJsLudwpPAFVD@bZh2ODr6EYywbTTkcIglJg@gGIFIP37IRFrcROWR8SSdzOcTQx5dADHE4HAMrxHpRli9RAFPxJRhEBLTD8bhCxwJyzaIoRmKZ1gvLptIOx9giLwZ/AJe03kKE2Cy@YABGylkhaQhzOE6XkaBFczgqFpyd1Nkyv8mkw5G3XpJJRHFOMh@2MnWBL0lyQSQd3kB6HY4uOLo6mJ8ORxucKMMOhwAuYc6D3xBcuOxeNXmHY27lA3PicMwINC8MHI6HpT@kA/ScnfE9syN2rWuuW08BgvIQJM/G2Vz79LTd7bb1eTJ7WiFB5@dnfH8@1tvdth2x/QCXhrEgaDCcv7xEDHp44JXdQRcQpL4Iepg/iITCB/4RKLOvLiY0fDjHoHMI2jWwZyOEawjAbbxSQ3im@LYVtLxIEHnO2m3HEQgthdWHnrvcT2Q4w0Ub8kIEreNivWPoZIc/jmOOSNRxeABPx0dHEJwzF806oZflcN45HO7b@P1HRzTsOHR@/OhzfsN9pB3RuOPQEY06aPeRLppjXaUDR8@YziLBHuHzEU8Jo3kv3vFMH/eTDdc@ekYNDF28p0fXwpPgvAv3RyTMBZ3IkMN9CIQePTPMMVZ/rK7wpJdam0zlAFzM4QNVTq8ALD2xque0zwd6nIYfGD8YPkpYeXY54i7skgJB8fidg3QirUF2l9MZDTidbucRIPlAzvGiLTqRdkLfMveo5iH38YBjmXlX3Ad9a9oXB8pf0aIPDg2T13G6hSR1SDsicQd64/lk8VfNyCevj/MeHrTDxyf/5NX13/yTXdduX7woq6GLcNTeM9XBvfOhOH2EXfIn6vnp@fhkmeoFPZ/zHt/y9Rua7nr2qX0n8sAZ3B7eSSaS3Upy2ddOpqk9X1ALaXv7@/vU3nHtxBF0lPwPq7GrE4aMft7h0CgOJfrvHo4/eH6ngS2f/@TTcgwXSGcoXcT1hx08AtoaYIqFsVC6tLHn@R0vSIRKAE7qCEcsHHtY@wRFG@OgOX1nZej4hz0yAEWXn6SxSiagDy9xutHFH1bJgSa39yA3PxRl5SkW9J2QCRuU62ciGEKJDKtTe6pmO4GP0Os2xZkJ1SAcdqDUQZGNqvFvo9/Gvr2sl@ql3Cf2MHYYI0y/u7Nlxcs5OScpxodP0NrJlSy1R3@vhbkf1POjvcORMxhyBlcld5fYs9jERd17J4Go3@Dne/f2smtXCDzvrWm4ALfX3L6mWy8TMs5N7cUuv8Pux/IEYjlAXAxD0/vPx8/wf/J8e3z8fIwLmOCB/9bt@dkKJ/9I2vKFPNbXFtwaZh3@uwmS/2Hv/gffsfV/jLd0yWKCIxJ2uPe@S5xA8RrfPnz7sAdqJk47AqRQPIw1xjHCE@DxOlDJn2gc4N@3a48DiH6wehOPDww6fAJ9EvBjGObOfRUAiyYej8Qie9RvgWHvLCKB0NWsqiSKujEe7ppWTeryJY9TzupqahUcl@MFHnT4aXnM9NL0odH2wXUDaPxs@tn20IYXOZ19229uMLjIFX3BesZzvMmnAmgJ9awLBwFNsliRPsAtOLiW3009UV8BrrFgkvWxcDuiqK9woSa@upZwXvobw3RjN4t1U199Zbcahuk3zAdEjpFsTx93RD1TyB6@0zFocswjjg5bGwB4XPaojayNqsqctiIZpPWzrDiydh/T3SD4gJYsKiA3BzRJkVCOmbOS/8oCa48lJCWXL2QhDnTXJLJywo7t0Nt4CCrJ3gfJbSdOs@CFWBCccIqAIyCgA08Xwe0e4i4DwUUgPTSH4RJZgQFQYNR6CSVeWrIj3uLrPURH9BLoKgMQW6m7rBzQBw92snYelo0xZgJYiLkjrR1ptPWu4LVLDw9wur1300/LtcwuDIX@cmC92NrGBYVhfcCARBSGHftAx8SazQQbd@@Foj2y1sS6VnC2z5pRz9SB6R0eWUU1OqIuXIL7CWfoj34YfvON8O3odnh/5B4mTHx6PENoegcu2QI5MBPDBIjH6Fa@PzJvPR75PjF0X7jwHc9NZQFYsphtuO28Qc7VBNCCq3gMt3dxq/p@UO@9uVvVAySPvQc3iYWXT7DeGfxksFsU72OCs/MBaZqJhUc94o/hh4sFttYbg/3h4Y@2vDDKwKUkFrf8fQL4oUBEjycHmQE6jVvF47l3Q@IKBL6OeKR88w3vUU5mR4rP50aob4Mfc7cmOO49CXw/dPHHs4@L2zHEP3TBMwHJKG4gHuLZvH5e0Q70HQGPrTJdk27ROEPyZkDeMJE4uPl4cHOQ@PBhcTvzDe@9FvsP2bU0IPEzJP5oYz236@DGTb9gCRnOdzm@lg@/9oNydHhljweY7B1txLQoPLiBkJHHs6T6GfUlOVZ9uRAFJcxeg2ydEEmOhiMTQOSwToOcB2t2cDcGxE0agizb4NY2mpEMPWkez2n3ksNSeQKBYfZ3HjDwbvbxI7VM2l72CimjcmmLNI89cnLKt45zC@SbIdaOs8/p111qeKlzV/3Qav4mS0OfNxjZqK5ENZEKZ@jCLYKgGnhin48sjWUtdgZlQ7QHwBDtgXA@1CLIJFtP2JAJOxBKa1lAEAv1hGTtlsSTBQ3UT2ghr2o@qBCLDKjMO8iQvf0E0U0gTzK4aPmYpAcOqCrUV5AJpAHzIN/TJ6DI6G@@oe3X4wR046PYFiAYwvU9HAK9ohQS/wJKAQdS2QcZRX1IEgHavsIQXMy/lVDoH5eQvRfHBRE8fa@1JcdPtuS4xqph7URDvrktMrAsvvqq70mEbILgn3Q9ID6EPf92z27uD@l06bJcr2Url8kq3KHnFNs8D3n5zYFXJ42P8ATxtqySBekCX@HE1rlA0y4wZk08@w0/KdKhz@sFOhAoZrx4Uguwfs8amYMG9XCFSTTIKZiGX9O7zFQeyMz2B4zw6w9k7Tv5XJJveXAykkMaZ2W9P269Pc7A0TBozO3jJbbOKB6KhmEfoO5bfpSG7O8lOwWHuOENaqF94DpZVrhcGUXW4eH0l5es7tTlrky@NNKzEGzFJwfrmlZ0Uj8oPCi9w5s8SjQVj7HsIc160cEtHYGlI7h0hJaO8NIRWTqiS0ds6YjbDm6JmbMwQzc3GIysndG1M7Z2xlfOELt2rjGEAmtncO0MrZ3htXOdWmiVWiRG8NJ7S26SqivqGMaFYssw3BgLXRr0DAMa7qVnCAgNvIKE6KFXnpBebNszGmfthPJMCYECgcj6HbTPEjbhsqjyWnR4rZStN9sT2irK6rwRgc3qOmil7Ay/DAFC5z6kcb8PRYHapQVF5MEYEE2wUhI5kH/RfWjtg9Xnh@s9P4ghwa3eIToeuwxxOPKRE0t8dgQHdgVb2AI7sVk7kOkVYzY2TNlEWlQebrW0FsbQlt8m1g@oYJGjb0AELAgsg@0dVss0a/p4Z5LB95PcQrgzyVdEWXjDu2Ihb1wEeWIZlbT/BFtimZ5lp4iktMEMsD9pRWTgRYHihujEE3fo@M0v/@x/o3/zyz/5Nf3jX/z6//2P/xO6/wPe/newWejACuDnf4K3f4O3f4W3v8Dbn25EIvDBQ8ePf/YreP0f/x3948/@xAr6l3/p8IZWiCAEvdYxf/FP8fYHePs/Hd7wCvAXf2QBYhSH95naMq1cAPXzv6FpSA2xrJD92V/RtMMDBobLlrxbq47fb2yftBCs2HBLXPcvw607fhAAeMy6PQ7Aa79x6zcPFoB7A7nO4zea1nUPzBlrMT5qaYEXerhFzvbSDLR/BDRhNMPfBXmbdsDosQcxnJD736cPaacHYdy4XLGDfRyiw@382/l2rEMR1uNggDo8Mt1GRT6XsKIEurcUyDfpCcwNP3ZbSI@Us2TE5m8RvwG3bEAcS8kip8dTdlrL2NDpoe0v6ZDPCSy7uii02AxZ@6jJKfqUvYeL20hwS928KDZI5aUPdBnXOys3oxIPcTiCIoFoK34jY/GFcMH7Et265Oxqky3lXlQYvNpgYg42NdIqoQTtcHwGFjltw7vR4gpuw1v02gC37GHwfmuf5i5gx/X1tYPa8GNRhvSOi2DYyJSlMlZB3HZQYCMosBEENFs4ia4JBwIvaCANB@rF7T3JVrQNFbUdbS1cWHOW5YBkQF/QGub0SsrY6CVeoyYaeVvZvUa@gZK7T9j15E4lOueEdrhfRQCc23ESL8tyN2r2FczrgtodE7m95bNVWm9j2oqzUSkI96iXXFqVHBffVXLbCb6Dmrv3fGFCAfYfmZDvCxOKhD@f0Mtixbhb6N/m7@fVzlJNrDT8GplV8fe2GihsGv8MRG@tjpBinThdbujyJO0uT3uq0a4dn0wCf2Z5NNvWd5L0jQPbsBNT1EzRGh74NNKgy6GhFbzxocVdX1i1v2vYVTVdNDb3X8vWDjXViScACFpXhVbNi0fEyfZHwHB@3jokZrtdWbVsthWatr7diKgtRqHl@fAgq7L58ADGpyK51wzEV7@A24acFH70EVwb8V0r07Y0cml41KXp/jxOYu9a0WqyMHCVRnagExJJ0tChE0QFOl90Dz8HY2gWSzCL1gdiwCJtmy43MrGnDbWuqGp4@AHGfoE@v8aNBPGjEaHFS/NeWtigyO5EuwQv77ajXvzkqPRFAD9otIwf2EawxQwvrb/kMXJW35Hcw5vJWdGW6VV/Or3VTXqr79MrybphvqSZeOJoDz5/WtJB1xoDAK7JCH6eDK993skrcrZIWXnjp8isCF9MYkc0BGj@kNIkgCZtcL8E8uFdvRnwtiK88Rb/3y/AZfTslxYfMWarc9A3Q/LlINJFM8gxUaogugA870bd8zq5lWhnvjAtu6NDenhe2kEUl4q7z6Bijkaiip/msa4l4s/IPC4ceiX3ZDVRwgrcQZM@8dKDwNtFlHnoiAo/FzsuG9K7gXeZ44rId4i@@rKMo6IjSk@zvj/nYr3clilGdgkToMM3RIb3Ttzut8XKApFX0kMm4wiF@bf5RwbuXqpmHARNWHMgmg4adI8cJESObxrNR3PrZAHF@u6trUet9scqySIeuPBZhgAfrG9Qcd51su731GfFtcrSF7QIK1j/dpZx8/ASI27ffV2GP41Fn88pGWVYRUosS3nLOnmrxOX3SnxDKpYyaVklXyaSnxO6L5a5DVGzkK1VWPqnNSGvMKd5RREE1yZGy@fdEtPUVzoB/bDENPWNVuVhh0JdxSSazsRPdSQs@8JNyeDMw3MCzwY8ESH0QR8sgVrmDe3a5ZAXCRnyow2rxfa5FdAW3eCie3MecQOKWrpxIPd5labwZprCqzSFrTRXNWA7yQ0gSthK0i4FLJ73ikARJfMN7YxB2HOHx3tqGy5V43Wce31yys5D2Us7J85DUMhO0XmYdYFSdnachxniMJyHVeIYOA8vwLGuW87vnYfLaoEAOrwSxyf0t1U4vgvOw7TL/UyRr50v0/U7D1dlCjAfrVfCkWdreLVtz/prq1FVET8uiEall0aJMeChYbZu773kx8I/AbVP54PADwk6cECAsQOy1WhstBhWOtBs@MnXlF27mo/D5dCUPb6xHkOBcE9iY1AFpWRM9JFzz7mtjCzCMJQMPsITCES9ebibIpp71TP7HDl26jJ@1hGYvZ0@4Z6f2AMdFwm/BeDNQRxlHX9ZXtsorAL8Mjox8lt0viJnmRyhCBcDuHeQhUz9zvlOprCsX5z0ZpX@Zgm9HiPAQvQtQaxSImg3dDrYcGibksRG2mhbSEgozvbJm3HwsislSu@LaEQr2DXzjWDibecMFcNm5Xe/l52NeEjalgrCwFv23qplq3aB6GIMWuu6DUvVqnxAwobO6ZCjV0QU24ztJHCWuvGStuKtZmgZ10qSaK5tNQmR/bizc8ybVurreRnc7/nTuq/LmGCCA42IYCPmKhVLv2o/wX7XLPt9aVAvmfAigV2G9e6m9LV5/W4r@4JyZZ3s6wLEQC@dce80jlYprFkOvYMNy/w9WXtl4uMX3Cwj30p0hf2Ftb9k26pP8Bm@vexbWLjQStAn254DHJgdBN5m1GuLRJn4l0aLH1Oy8VgZX1G6ztr7tFoZ31XEGIJtNDx@cgHr2wW8WXiIj2RAf8Fyq5bj57nJPMWqbpMPOq9nLqxZBw1Xia3OLdzwBHVP1q@tlmiBR@mhkikVCy1odKPRqPv1VATWWoi7bsepd6cJVt2WgBePnrK@x6zhShrd/HCnOl4vKSMeYAzwZN7GEj@7jrttXbahz1/UXYhnwW5w1MY1WFcDfksroanDY5Mt23y1vh7gOuBtJEvzFvjtJb01nDVC6cAJnYcH0nw9PODinIcHuxXDollNI/12z/6AYGC9XoPa217NRCwu49X5LjgAMB5aH1C2B@Dsk1usdSh7@K1ncxl7FWusmvJysQOOD9nfa7bm8l1BDkcn8tLKh9CBizJcgRB2YQNh3ChvxUJoHPgkSyvtdD5Yhg4eYGyMNJUcQUmO9SJmOx6nbCyHXgnZY3XKk2UgVipkf/8GRdaCrOW8mPWVaJUczQtxcY8YGUJe8sZLi10/mfEJxKHLMZBH1smEq6UfhptEIgSTNVrA47YiDoGkKsjujtHkSxlKpZeTu10QJMb@JIa1wKXGQ1SfJvnSyxN39ugGr8id5dmv9powcu6yPQ4M7HRtHZlk0IEIWFNxL3B2/QPG4jIZGo9FYskiLQIFvyg8opYz5t2I@8E1d28/ueXlRnwfXA9YstbmUFnHz19MeHWDz/ae0Y2haXvSkuiBjZnL5elflH1aW4LMU/pxjdrI5dhzLM9EQ6e1bIJXhOVhQi48xuqQ@koligdXgNGCtbYGDFwVjTYyveZeLUlV6a/pYIB80hfSI1YqSRZwWDN7W9ghDKIisdbqPlvBOL7uOL7GyUTqqz3UhZasYfylKKObnAK7lmX6g43OmlDBqmxVgeVLeOMlCF2Nr3Yk/MHl8AAWj8Pt2MIE8Pbsx1eW5n0dFZSi@7dMrRNp5rRkMlkbcnrlNNlN9pKVFryn2IKn2Q9lGSZ7pnSSmXx7fqpFaxMpwNZaV6l20FOOdmYj@WyYPhtlKTnUGnpugrP4WWgRTgfTSYG9lk4LUiiavpauDTGpiHFm0h9cdcTKqM3phnxRvCxWFkyuftXoXvWlm2azH1Wr1Khyk@pezcSrWFOdNOrxvHElNtJFc1Dsm2NuXoo2I/WpaqQatVTvfJ6fDmb5iNaSw@krMdqQRmdTYR4eCWd16mZS60WqZ/NBnBt25sm00WlFPR6mlU51Y2dC50Y6r6YvOl093A4PqnE@OBmeS6N57@JMfSz009WJ4Bn1c/nIhFLL@clUDDUHbeVMvak0Gu1MqjwdcMbNqNMPNS/HZjumR4LBcVLs9UPh/NjUY4VU8iJqZpL5Rk65bpg380asTJlnZi1aPxfiimdSMoXgOFNnDLYxO5cvqtPIWaCmnannSr5fHpyOT8vKaDzIhORSbRjSu9e5thYInF1VJ2etAqWHzputWKUfiGWEmcBchDVtGKzFiwX9cjZOPZbEZlqopsR2hE2Fr7Nc/7I0F0qTQqXSLI@a9WHUuOCUmxzbp0rXQjWZGuQKwxhXK87zsdN8dZxO52eTdkDqaslxpxm8vI5MC0Ux37xigmf82Lz0yOmSwvTPz415o36Rvy4aN1CtL8/lkDSfpRopXXrMpI3LSoEp6oNeNdRXO6NGVE5rwnk5HzLzg@TZtHkTz6cGolRuD7RBrak0x6ac6TM5ap4eXNXb4jQnL6Z8NlRoXDH9bEUwo8lusMr0Jak9UErGontaWHSr43a3Ey@dshnx8aKTaoQr2RF3mTNCRXVOtWopSV5UriRuUI6f5W/a2aR8qYbTZXFUPj2bzAKBliyVp@EFN7vu50LyTAixhVLq@tJzdR6oeAqeVKqsBUtdKpDJnTa74QuPlhMXTEHiH6Npjz4eh2aZ8VjWxUJdVfRhWGFjuZqnFzX0Zvzycto28teVdFNQFrGby8EgclOhrid5Q9MDsfNcMs6UB6x@yveL@ZuorOZC09Spko3nm4t6zMwWxkrsrNDNnFf0TG0oXMez3ep8PujGzsVyYZCkxFimUum3u432rFU1ynP2MiT0257sabb42IV63KjmAuf1VKQ7rgQbFxl1Uq7lPAvtulkYpYsDLluOjSO1aHBITWbnsWTVVOVR5vQyHrkay4VsMtOtpzlNFK8fhQtuwFdrczZmRPWr3PXVyPCYtbYWavdSwfnVZYtp3BhG@EymbmbNSD450IWLzsw8N6I1NaCVrljuSirWlfCkKT@2ylo/OWQu6tcLpj1d5GZlUzCrAy3ciYYHpzPjUV9c6BdUrNXnlXoxrRX6QuSiJS@iTJhTa620dCm0zgNsst49uxRzZ5Puoi4OA/2zx/GZwAtGOdlqnyqRyWzkkYKxSYGqFZvX3ejjI9sWi624nBzUK@W8GajxzLhVLYQfCy3DyAn1vJwKyeo4k2qdDobpmzlfM2aLcS3SVqR5WQ@wWWpWbF02hL7WNXLGjdBfXOdu1MtxIHJd6ktRszPghjJXaEhstDiqeDKesnLa7s4jjbE4EcAyHF3lR1wq2e@XqBI3jE5S87hhqqfGRbGdPk/KyWQhFrgaBaJng/Tp2awjN@qN4lmH10I37XQwUmp32UAnVcx2y6FhN1ouRkOFNFVrz68qXCcTk7ker6T75/PQKF4IpCJMY1o5u@rXempRSSebMykVFGraNNrkJbUuLiJR5pL19HvxczXJhsoRqm5mzHohNw161Iv8ZaA8nwvXbX4c5KXHluERWoveotQQeU3pFR4rXK0xLqTlfr8RSQk1tpSqsuOFMeVHhTIVz5RVLlOYTXLTXrXJGqPM2SjWnhU76XJZbI86wZHULiVnEjtpNm@uruoldXh9NTyrRNulRYfvhxumVImUZib1CCZPY1Ko59qzjGRI/crkUT2dja8bTKh@OizUOxNPP37TmgTl6xJbKKYaEj/OX3WjZr04G12eK5LCDAOlLkNN6@XFwhSTWrY4vWzNpMZikZRTxiM3u2D4wmk@c2164tlcMlOqVXldKZVOC5kkP5xeTgvXUY@4qF52wvLg8YYqq6oS0G@qSjTFBo1APZxZpIX@KTs@TQ1r57U4N@LqZ43LywuupwhDIdoqZSLNS6GZTJ5fzM8lvlEuj8oX9RpV8qjXNzc1plRTCnGpkK/UtHB@ol82m1F@qiWveDYfGranhVlqejkeN4fxc0/LFPmgthBFrjJVCox4BrITo8TxpJwulo154HHRf@xOMtp1I54cnUaS6bnUmYiTBZvMTDyMkZtNOxF5FAvUWrNTqSVcdrsXlVQvOJqMapF0mDqPS5dqo53uXcbn4sVZoZEbm2K10w7JHoMd9WtXybpRF@byqRDpTepGS4HKJ43CtVQ6big3mdiFLnvYmJCihOYlX2YKvfB18byjTdOzy8Y8A12OGCeV2bA2Vxvj2EA9uzBSF83Hi1isW2@fDSDhce@mJ8h1T6rTFq8kpUjdXF80BtnyuMH0r64vo@X6mSe2COqnj4LWO@Xj89qixLKiFO9O8uNZcFQQYqexi5KgnM@KlbokdiPVwJVyqi6ojBrtsUmJm06mKuOZh1OxbFdK1YuqnqkLZ1FRK/MMM2vemKXmdewicMpesdXhlA0Yl1OGlVqqPG8VW61Ah0pNjItRs8pNsp4zM9mq9ivCqcIUm5X8QpsXsgGjniympYvxdD4qzGU9eCMUTtNKWZA5MEvCkW5Nrw8WqUmbakqzQjoVi94EzkCCDEOJT1shXhSMUXfWZwqX4zNl1h8PGrpnOGMqnpvWLBzvNXoGIxQKtWJ@mtXD2rnRV6lIRAicNfVR1Kg8Duf5tJnpNepKKB1vdNulsxZzWZMu4lfp6k1UDJeZ/KMYb1YjrFAINwWGq2jDiQktktAdUIU529EFRdT56Lj0GM6Ox57OfDI2PaOb6OlFrNkdpLmJwHuCybb2yM8a5worF6Ni1yg1p5PrXBMsRLUxqatU7qY@Cl7IZ1L1rFG6HHDlZGVhMql4U7gOdVs6J6nSpBI0w@d5sRsVpEz2ZtDPnOUf82xLemSnnKJfXQVzZxwVlTwpU@soTONqdKUuAryYbJVil9POIj3sFSXxLB/I6K1KpFO94JUsNKPyY4EdNXKnhZtOW@kxkqaWqhWWpW4igWzzuvLITTpX5UVNm53p3fNkWQleS3lVK183uMyVzhSjqdxVul@5Sc9jkbKutMVaN1ZTh57ToCbwSbUQoaLiREw1mkxdlINcdLZo8wOR4W6ag0HsjFlEjAWTVI1pP9ZdxNunQ655U9ROa/MBczqc3ZRT19xY9HBcWRhRV@aiHD49bXou5qf1fFep5yWB4YfzvnGWGovn0/ZVJOmJjdiaJ9tp9GaFcnfUzDLRdjvGVYPBZsh87JTnxlWRamQKZ8FoZm7OpOxgXJzFzkbJSHU@q1@FQoOb/qwUq0Yq4Rk30QbZ1CjXDTPatRFVZ7Wzbi4lZqVLybhctIUhFVmMi/lcLOsJi3yr3LphpSzzWO0oZq8r1S6ug9UII4TPSuXpzU0myQyjUj@bV06hTZzyl7N5td8atK9KRlCmtFLLk48sIovqzVWxo5ab55e99rQbjZb1s0Y/Pl60RhW54hkt6vm2dpopD5XM4hoELlKJh/t1JVtvyteZCluizEgzOQUbnEsV5HmXyYfZC0llz2fD0/j1sBkZtAaN9KTSmg36kWo0rI3FRdRsPobHYj3aOh9WGaHdmvY8gVNKqy7m19mrkF4oTkcFs6yJF2wsULgZ1IfZcd0zTF/k2ma6yY7agWZhOvakw2AVxC4b8UCxfdFP5QenV8bZVSBO1XLyfBzrn0ZOPWVoTMZ9oxRrKAFlwjQZpTGdiIMhyxczfEOfteu5QqfYCcSYkUeOTs2LyON5q3zDm6OQylDGPNKZ8p6zLFgQGbkVrnoa5ogdQl@EvZ4EL9RuMGCo19WqYKa16KAejIuhnN5QtcZM6zcC8tVpdDAV5Is@lRIXnZBSrzQ7xdli2okPQh2@Oqknc9dqM5hWR72ZoXOR@EWgwT@Wh3qwZI7KhbqQUq@GPC9NPTMllbnUqxOq0y0mO83c41iaNEKlZCg5v@6wofHNpM@pi@tsK9Avt5M9aVpphhaVaTDVOeXUylAeDfUAw9YaanYQm9XPxAvqfJEV573YVarcCNUv@vFBUOkOqmV2PijJknBzY4y5fKtbuOI6@XAjdRUfnElGUozW49J5n5kV26WbSLojhljK08sPmUC6IATPs9ce81xQwo/ygiuai7ikzot1uV3tTpKjQqdfHxdTZ0yKC0xOZ6Vh8KzCBMd8ahjLXOgtXaHEbDg5q5cuI0bvJmk2Qlo5MImNbspy9zrQKfd4YchGYqCDLzvtm3k9WUlNC63iWdVIqt2F6NGnF@ppPpdLqdSZ1Cw@Go@8Jo2ToXqp0Lp6vErq3Vq4bRp5bvYoMvO5WjpPC8K8lcwbg2LjvKrmo@ywk7qMXvU6BbWuleXgBSXEo4PrKKNWhfMxK4bKyVDusXEqPOYnkYo2UE2hlr3hzGIFlF0@XC@NWtPhIt1jpVkwlL02St3O6AZqa39BBcZnlVanIvXV2bRybjYugsMqN2hMlUFE5UeeUDZeKvFcN4idsPC1pg415aJrXleLkwudYXqLyFgcnYoXMlUIjLrJfCVyHuBPT1uZeJ0bPhbEQOwyNE5OA6XKpUcNi6NMvjtU2PSg0hevZOgyNCPl/jlbLcr17s04fR2fV6lFqy3F1fPmVLtID6aZwaRfq8@C0L2qNQqGUa1cm538JNA@jyrtUq9Ty@TSV0Ka541oSU1nS4PRuNEeTs9CYaqfC173L6PncjcyiObFeetiPIqXzxf5dO8s5Gmp5zGzxZvKY0npPxbbptl@jMqN6tU500xFBZV9nEfN616TMaiz2DB7GhKji3yPi9bV4WQ87pQqqpafl68ugc3RQLB22maSo@ZV2Wx0zkTh@qwOlv65Juar1@ej6un1WWfcUSklCOKbZvSL04KRu84MbrhpvjJvy5xnULqYlsLRsBRveybhYbE3zoTDzejwvDjJZUZ6ZHYJWr9bnpcLYqV4SXHDy1Z24DmXOC6mXy4ak1AlKV5H2pdTaRoKZ5IztReL1dnZ1fmpcBVrj/LTYf2c614x05v4wBjydb6SFDSpRKUeR8F5ZmZm2XD2InJ2fSX2I9NOdhzIJ6fVZj5ixotSsxl6nFamA7GY46TabDINlHOlK1MNhWeNq5vBBZRCmBK6s6tsVLwMiR1WXtyk9ZzWVut8kmXOmcC03rjyaF31sSh6BuVALjiKZNlZmYee8U1qfN6JtOt9pXmaOov3qE5IyHpqRiR/E3m8fryU9eu@JzoElROTKpOrSzBJ2ma9FppdSfEWt2ikY02@nVtw2QsmGTo7G8fzgcB5IV5oUUY1PARpeZwGrs8zSuCq3KiFxp5MMTPr9Ko39Up6ehm7aXHDcrM6OcfOWJBhp1KpX6nPi7lZXRYj2UElK6UoT/5qapTiI6mSaWR1ptyRcqH@4Ow0dyqOL4TxLKt62G6@Pp88jodi7PxS4UVdzVXMXlIItmKD4EzIj5KPFw1qfsZnz7l0rBHTB7Jw3i/Wjb4xaY4kORl6DM88ZqVfli/CmUrtWu3Xe8WiLqQvA1FDzAyqw8hNvT9rT8Rs55ySzPhEUGanxYippuY5@bp@eXXeqbJzoRw7L@b0Gdtmco9VdmIy9Vi1XOu2i7pc6EPD6WnVNS2mgEoxe9oVxY96eXbaSF50Yl0jfcrGCuezUl0uetirbKWfCRgT3cP0hqVAZqFlz4PSNNqtXF0MWT096fQ8F@Uoc9NPadMiFTY7wSZvDOIViWu1GswoW1kYxmWs3vZcXCmMWAncRFNnC67WDo46414r1hqeTh5brcvHdqN6BsV57REj1ctHqnt1cWZEpbjAdeqpdCGpTUbsuT6sSKFhQWvVAy3J05pl8tPHwAWb6@fbXLHYWyxSwrneVGOZYfsyzc/79ViDCmZLbOcmKI7O65nHVq437gvpwkwIXmtnhuc6VJyNT/VYNMKF4hPeCDaGw4YnllRkTzTYm/cCqewkkmE6eqVJZUuedFPToBZUbiJ8kTFCnaJiGvVorZqNV9K59FnhInstFeLVPH997Wld5dPZZC1yftEbhC5anJFiUpe9fjVA9QvpQYcxzdhYrso5I3uqZ2a9m8HVcNyeRicFo7VQL/ix3B1yEj8aNAtqNJK8ajyGS2wwe8lkbxaKGoiGZ3GqI0idc0apDK6bMTl7xrSUHnSgMyD/g@vLsS5IutGLNyHnlws1mq6Xug39TOmVgUKlPR4J0jAuD3pi8IaqMNVYLtpULiSh1KoMo622fF07D0al8Qz6r63M4kLKMFDq9Va1N2avI1kwXUOhx3yzN7yaFBtGJZxp1ArlENV4rGQkLp8tFBo3ZocrlthubmLWo7GzLCcMU4Nidp5qp/LTnFBvnnn6nkCtI0xyjaSSbXR4Yza/YeOsnpT6VKQfuUxJGc6chhuSHkqf90pBXslrs9J5bDSslM8DqfPslaQNdDZ1lVxekcY8PpTD866UTJ428q10l0pepTP9QEMyhIrqmeYJWCqn8L/9yUeFiLquEjBqoskd/ECUIdrHXBy9c/AEOXkCt7dvnTuBi302DxKQ7P3V1gdqvY467hA@tBIhc5t@/HgITi0evZxb9HHL4wTIA8/xoA/IB0OkrYlQh46RV2R8kNX3CCAznmQGBefByPbkr41D@AEN3iVKYBPZUecivHF/ljbCETznAw8UZe@PNqY8XdwmNUggFBmvSsBPr@NrPFXhG4hIpoCzpZx717Q@e7QVH4gzRio5acTh8ztIVPtUDMS0jcIqTfRfnc1AkQNZlhNr73wOjWe4GBuJk/M9aNVreoe38XvvgZBw0KIp8@rQGOv/X3HXutVGkqR/U0@RCNtIRldsd/cgoFuAsDXLbZCw2wfTuCSVoNqSSq2SALXNj90f@wL7APtw8yC98UVkZlXpAnTPnjPTZ0wpL5GRkZGRkZGZEbftL1fB9U1HddXg1@Zda/L7b0q9ea3g0Wj9hTgbLX23VWBPz9@z38y/sXPoZ8bXJzu3h6cv9tsI16KrSlk3V@VlleGPLP7ZSJVnuFS97BkuFCcfvfPvLrb6W8Vy77x/Ue6vrWVGa1ujtdJaGgkvSpnyYKxvIp6PLvjVfuGlOjRP6xEsBHd/g446Cfqt62A1VBzlPv7mhD2amQnUcwfx@XTjtUbBMJ7SAT@5vcREnE3CKbE7VdMPTLnRZODh6M56JegGxL/4Z2n83evybD56uLQEFxplfXci3oGvzmDc7PqtDWeJ6YkjcDyn39jQTmFaCny7tMRpviQKLsoP08gum9xWMJjoyr4UuTR92YyB3E7jbDWTfUpJU6pJPHmJ0G5DKiZFhLyJ4opA89FoRrDC94HXt@eg8OOTKcPLiVo2ecbjD8qDb9jvzuVI@eylh/5sKl2UfWCojPY4wannPh698VWC7VXJWvp13Bvw@XNe8NUUQdzay4HrD23NfDhu4nWvKoEYvkEaI4CPe3iEu3FHXnxozFjg4hs/vkJ/AO@Egw8Rwi0X0cJJNuLxAeC1A66zJIGR02oUyMVKQUPX5W5k9FAT4eCHfXWwuqH4HlyZkvhItBzL/ZVy0dcF2T3K7rmj6wXZ14A9DhdlDykb4ZIXZPuULW8i5@cHlC8n/QsKjHDLk9j1chRcjly/mxaHHnAFci8CO63W1gxhLQsoGRgZj2R9pV2jqGUZHWG2BHvR/GS2kgJg6bSePPgdcQvnwk19Wvgi1qbQRH1VjzamL0cSiS@5JRK7aD/zMgFfxRCg@UeiVM3mm8ZltG1HE/yTp2XnCqNNxHqlvn17CDPNiEn@K10Y7pMRwj3cWA@FWhEcieYajatU@l1Xml9Hu46JSzdzRyLqh5mU65EIkbkVzeuO329TGwR4OZ6MK08Z9WOUch5eqA0rPSI6yrR4nI7rM9yDG1E8I7OqGX22nk5VF3xPNV1akZuRsICfMLc8Q87Qls4lS29TaUvNKT5rJXhGz9I/29mn9WaF8ONJzbQpi6BtkWq4rRGcg54r4xqXCQLs2eqGpCP2rJ8E5i8AJv70LgnAaJNwwMpmxLhZE/1@Xt6kkpwvrr/O8hVzKXIfkckIq6fQ6f9hcoFweskeIxxfUiSpOaSZKW77DXptT0@5qe6JpJ/fuXN51Lz64ypwVLP8xFz3I62SG6qorOOmsrp/XA79Ncp8jYYvoe@E6cWywgy64cSnsOD9AkI/ymTJLqxfqATFgQJLhkeWJHZCOH9Riq7WX5oUc@1S5vZCDQxYlZP5wFkAmgxSlOO1slrn2o5Ep/a@eDkyyk020sIQBVe4glT2shMX59jO7fPiHU@1rqOYIvEcvGSHhjk0mPkdo9uSGmzq5VuXGGYhMuhJc/oqCNppozBphYEhGA8dVCgr7qysWiXqZdQ8NaeVXnWlvXyYdbdMKcs6idcVSoDyqXkTSLy84mlTxrSJ6Td@yEGaOR@rETVlXh/gsqJIH7UxnY7SVgVamlvJSHz4JGPPlVrO80qcEA@pXbePi6EYDtlab6aQbgcCZbZpox35t@QxuJ9jZRAfntq75df41sUv@3noxHbQzS3ITNlis7mZQjOW4e//WFkujMNhoen3C17/hpTq5sRZUV5fogVuqPGok/sBF4Urp2/fa2nC97L5EiKxCY0UWsv3vds0ypDmDC@iqYwjPun40mLJgV9ivjfe9W7apPWLx5ZBEN7xvxPaLBTz48Eo4BzdEPuuU9/8b5E/1SK/ItI7Bo3OJsOJyqTxvkBSJ3JXMlcSBakEn8uZGIhz1GSBm/qUSmH8gKi@T3p@4YR5z21dAwnw3jfZTtFwMSffO6EZevhaAynweIU@u@JlYsB3R9EEayfhhH9T9/G7hA9J4Suu4Hu9T3H4QjByukEwAJPjKijqbxIBhPBL9cZe9fQ0ryMsyY113HKXe8x4IsgO6zheg73Gi9vqcBcog7KEzgK2tLcVAWf5yzRCs5pMmAq3IKfQCv4IpQe5Ev@a6YYtn5HiTBJ@7qR/haBlUXv1GJAeBdpF1dKxajlTzRSOkWLpUWq4rRYcQRx6vYAw3vW6XUJaaLEUkQOfoIhpf822H56jzQuLvOTnZvJzify85AtSUal863oYFdqIF0qtfI3K3atUVCw709aWok7Xjti7VD4YxvAuP1Q2zNMmzY8Kb9uhFK60GZuJjFws55c5oy85y4k6lsFt/rnka/5e1yNvsUyU/SnZPv46eoA89sGgnyxOcWm@73d/FPOjzWEJq@BWSapjvJntZFJqg4gWJzkSE8TEPG23tyIoayUjcXjOpLY3f0rltUnqx/Q0GhIgcGZizZkjMSpxm2tMuDteSagdzl6OgWCYYDRlZu62qTzRlScxsCi1bJp1jKfQ5ASnrk1P8S1c6/6Gf8xkTyJnyq3Mz1wSzO@k8/LSIkkgFrrLqflkSkqT0XDsSaLu1AOrSNT2ZBrifCFxFGAH2rqGpLBtevIepBOM@@1lKyfigsJIihm62xxN6ahAybDvoiFE5r3zR@Gl89btkVbY9e5UBTq1y576ncRjm5EXjkKaAx51cKjC8WDQ9bVfN3XLzzl0rKD1N3iMEEGMKQ15p4YHolI@iy/9OIYq5dUxIN/inWGUEY6vEKMdlmCEGyfR2vEJ5CjvVPoT9kzMbtDW5cmLp8bw4woB3KVtXwwJGTmZPWx5gJaWd8zDIulqR@Z3f0QqEHU8YJ@HcLW64Tj/GPutL7tv1Xqx@H2p@KoUI5kxVRfzr16rWkxFMhnrxVKx@Kb02nF2g8FEnjamWxnAep0DwKw6wEL/nnjTu0E4cKdCKwYXDEn1D73hjdfOO86p12YbcHPMFAErj0GuvvHzihTSreDvntTdXphVtO26hnjBX6zP4ru2xY41sg7eEA28Yc8fyUuj4MZvg4Dm3VQn6HaDWzZE48mS0AOVet6IiPIyo5IosV9ajQvrLuwulqiBmA/swK8Z3LAfaU0G0lN9uN/nB0AOnCgCQryxfnsKE2qv1XX9HthpDgLwshRRwCBAXWuPW96DODiMxJ/EQemOtYPWGJ55XTMyBZJ@Ac8Vmu7e0CfpGxGYR4WrxXCnAW68q9VV/Xi/8aFyWlX0fXJ6/L62V91TOx9V411V7R6ffORoYurd8QFJl7qqHO1R6lHjtLZz1jimhFSlTjVTnOFUjj6q6s8np9V6XR2fqtrhyUGNoBH408pRo1atZ1XtaPfgjBbrt1lFENTRcUMd1A5rDSrWOM5yq6aaE9VTx/vqsHq6@45@VnZqB7XGR25xv9Y4QmP71FpFnVROG7Xds4PKqTo5Oz05rlcVOubs1eq7B5XaYXUvT@1Tm6r6vnrUUPV3lYODqY4efziqngL5RC93qoRlZeegyi1xP/dqp9XdBjoUfe0S8QjBg6yqn1R3a/io/lyl7lROP2Y10Hr1H2dUiDLVXuWw8pY656QfoQqNy@7ZafUQSBMl6mc79UatcdaoqrfHx3tM63r19H1tt1ovK@fguM4EO6tXswpRYblpgkHUonz63jmr15hutaMGrRlnJ43a8VGGBvkDEYawrFDVPSbw8ZH0loh0fPoRUEEHHoCs@vCuSumnoClTqwIq1Ilqu414MWqQiNiId1MdVd8e1N5Wj3aryD4GmA@1ejVDA1arowDBRLsfKtToGfca40R4yScxq2M4N8vDqWr7qrL3vgbMdWnigHpNcwuTbfedpjnN5YIz98jtwQO82VM@bQp52En87vFelTQ@CQSTitLPaNH5IXl4l8ijhcZm0k99Cspr1WXba46vLv1@J8DW3FaTE@xeeJVFnKUMIvl@ch6IN64PyrnCysrl5fvKJe1z65eXmexTaibQeKyG9sL6UKmM7mM3cNu8zU/YluKE2n6hfb1nxfFy3NbywhofMqpQaHu6Gh4vArAxE@mgBASsDcnIrxrdvoo1yUfMSVsRR8yYNhaZ480gpH/636IfsjbEEkg4y72FQgF7WEYDkU@UxZ8a4aAgOjII3wPwO9xkPvS8L1fpYrw5bPm1gSpj6nDZEW0Dr9KZR6o3vaup6rnp@ows3pqysmLcwRs37WDMgH9pkik9Lvkh9ywtpj3@kzHYcEOkFGakKX7Iqm@fpF9IdfgXFVthpmxdiXM4kMPKz7UP2MwV11@Xp9Lf2XSZW3h1jtg2tN6dc70L/vPuQgrQBPOx/SKS@BM5Ui0UYnVIK2N90haGr/prFLr127SmYqm@9nhZh4d8cRccr0@L8dC/i2NPYvjtaeVw52x/nyQnsH39w5vvvys72uP@cPRzVv5@RDsIucnUJS361ic1jbNis2SX9J79mWA5seg@GD0URAhKM2ic6JJKaz1nio4g8TXEDITuhogw0EeQjRSCBAxTCu/zvWXH8OvcmakZIJ3oaga96bl3rOG7pCoxD7TES2Z3wqN2h38A205/M8VthzQDaRbzeoPRhDiXNhcs91L7xuEA7234WTGK5FOGjweuuYMkhIHMZC8MeIPPvzRvx0aR9FoMNOYrDzvXJCSWp7EwQVo45BI1cRKEZgZLok8pP2t@o8@POjgQshDqoTKqExn3bc2cCd4jNmc9MTTki@0tGqIXL2xLmwqG1IxGSuz/ydAx8dnAqMiFBjUF2Nw8snS2OWyE/mk1o74Kp8KrN@CUNcfq38S587qjoZSNS3T920SQUQIrCijDSbe2DccU@WiKWHImyPQv0YPh/xtpMgf@Jm04CXpELZbDfn/sPZGSDFVoRbtXJop/a26Mxa6pRdSMJ32MwNzHB@badkxfw7uTgyUigR6diUn4KCHF0nMIACaHXSM@f@HAlyfxtUs7p5947i7JSf@w3@oN0iYgl1kqZuBeZFnnyporcviRkSP8ooo1d4D4Kj@xn0eWGdhwkRRrTtTzMCUw1kosc9Dpwks2ethZzqwJMpTMDI/Yqainlpn8d/qGUbTKtE3uPamii4N92eMQxBRKCHxzAmIECN99indYk43a3Aaic/sNTy9s5Vd6FUf0SxKBvC6rBrvnCN0O75mxFGlfGnDagSYB53lbx2xqeqNbLBddgc4@RCJoKv2c3ZigEW2LtGqEEb6ZPFGdF9lbiz2bKcGvFvuz/pc@oi97YuIyJfKJCFBxF6x5dehyMKju0/qdihpfA1m3k@3X@uxXpSXnlTDN8c6dWsFO/3kYUYQ0zltol7QORVRyW1@QmDI86t/m/Dv6w23ldM9NTCPaM3DEunlK//3CDQF4ZeoOrEp96lsj0oYsZFvPjfqCL5m79usjvrSdeYs6RchRCi7MajUIKENvwiXN2dnG@CXc6uDy6QZpTre3@aY77rn9jtvzuxO@dfprcN0vhP1xOMgPJk4qlUpaA@EIHC5SCPeRpz74/XZwG6odmg4wJNWPzuonScNfzPK1K5Yvpf5ObagdbtmZAd@Bz6Qw6IxoaLyymujQ58PI3MN2Qm1pYbPWBAlwTDVkBqJ2e1Yzfnt0pt56fW9I@uAJ37lUB37L65P4IGWKb2GG1yJpUHwfrdd162ofugtbdsrK89moY217jm5AQ8uCtdI0FQnhoQ6rCNv8hFg9ZhPMz3Y46lfbGJWug4H2BgSjKZRNMXF2xt2sg9iNH2qNd9iMy8acbTO0rBlbH2yJojr1xFhLnRm6/dGEiOJMG28I7cdsN3nFzoAIorOYnLyp6yF6extmv25IXUXcei0FeAWhqer5NwgWx2a4p4wR37PVZrOIbmXtXzEr4euM6EiMnhONXhYxQ/NZ9eZvquGBd9VJ123RDkvVx6j@6hXpgTtBOELRw4pSxfVSqZQrvYKJ9qxeyfNEwP9NBDHHqR2eHJ82iJDaRb5hDLtmgvgctEtuYxE5cgjdRb3/DIFsypPEXP/MxIMKbvz4pspyYpHaSNHYt1yYe6mHYVIdZpMsTPLBkAOHwRsUsVBiOlKrcHqAEH0sJNFSDHqWQ5fp4GOytFg82ZsfV/gM3LrEV12ch37mypxGAsC74zSqNeSdQVu7vacx6Xk9i70/Mqu7KwWc6ZhnlmBiSyXmWM2uQksi6mXicNoe7kiEiB7QC29aQ5It7g2xHK6wGJdYxDMsmzK2N27T7/o0Bwiv1nWABUfElRkINkHEI6I5POI21g4WJMZlTrQCml3toGeLClaOY53B6fRBOGkFauWKttnYaYUDz2tzpITxQEIBID9Ps7xLK4e4iduIYgQ4K0W@NzkkYYOQLCT7xl34joWvv6aMuWN6Q1xl3As2rrGtF0DUo/qIJykitqXn7LCzCue8GR52lxgCdTMgxAJHfwRikMWhFGFF480MwV/MLlm4o@ryeE/7AURFDkYUDpIZgCWnul4yw4BH3/XnTAFh0i2LwJSLQYOM@MmS74QNLPkD/cW9UzhNS0sfqXOTjCXmvo8QmmIbCNRVgH9ROG8oJmeEHp8RzjguvINLXoI3XbI0W5JK2QAisZLrc2Dm5sJ8NR9mTsPUh5W1/g07bEMtZgvphXiDDkg@ghBR998GRvSyW7luIAdMtvdX3aCJuE0kKag1/Jlko4GNJ/MOLEHoeK44EUzGm9o0XdKo67dNRndRmzQ/vG21aSwW25/6MlA6Y0vmEvssU7x28XTiT/yjZxR/phLBq6B1TEWvAnqSSrIbYFMapE5JbahoZuImTry8bjlZpZeoUpqqopFLVmkmqqw7kafSqdFFDYh@/E32zOglfCuJR0Bt2QEqOj33TnY3RXZAx2YahIxMeMRbv9AMgoLnLWV92qH4hRO5aE4c20sb5idfweMb36lnKQ55VUzGO7gzV/dYDHCpRP6E3YD307pDGU0G/mHdP2cMMrpfm1ylH5NUtsOS4SS6PcRbrXS8lcyGWhm4cmqIUiEWtnjT50wDnNKn6L@XKq0byMWRlUJwq6tFIRGeXS@f01ZWhsXIwaITrcz8KybgaAQdkd98ZUyWgXQ6Ma@M5LYw5XNGdhMopAs4bskR/58h6XWSihUlJhrqUPgQxlQred4dbc/4jJlB8PpjLdY6UXwaW@mhkT@PWr4wq0ayFwtLTy8l88rEVhVLhYcKG2JbOi0svHi1YdLBhgB5J8VjpDuAkViTzizBq6GQjLUUf8TOToOWLxIqSbaY0JW62TkCODnkBrnsVK@cmCtz3cPpZcRJrJwJJknHfiFMu3ougewEUMZJ1AL9Fw04rjvGJ/bCciUpp4d9EUdYWGbcH2ILW9iM@0NsIYVjw/4wW5hYhpa0XH@aLxIjISTApUS9Y2CbUlwGmYy7eKm7qVKM0OQi7svc66bnYBuTqtrW6cyoSpZEOnRJsg3@cycDs6IdjSbYkYh3bkfjIuotrXGtL17bemTWvbdbpO1UckmQ0ZwORIBOmxZ4jC4yCJltK5DEFiOY3jP35O4me7RflQ0L70ERtevqOvm6NwHWrCrFzKxCabz3R8hvzkU@NxtFIdpibczGh7e3yzTWuPAUDNsonXLmnPg6j2C1FsMq2bvYCCVJvABS7kmQck@AVIhB0hP7Fa2X/LkyRJw67zEQnz7NwuA/v9BGSsMgSdv2YcTGPvjWnTwGc5mUrRW@U@fKrTJbIdKTH4Px4zQMjgt6bU/jdOK1C6vb794wmI7KsZCySV6Zg5HFamUWrSzQYqnN@11dzqhKvLfNf2le@3YnsPL4SIsfY10ZV4mv7SHQStKrvgUWzf/SAvplY8OanA@CeMIMQ9qy8yenQx6EEAuTPBWzFWKCLLkP1RlJQjycOy38eLc67f0YAU8XVss82pOfxOATMzqVqGsisRIcZ7ZwkXAyq5WRb/O2Z4@2vzK3/UEwIB2nMxcBLt@DHV@MUlMiPVJNp7bWT1rL5q5ns/2K621TsUmePslfzHR9nbqOh@k0qfverV79H4Ks@2JG4C9o8ueGRxYg@Xwukjhod7VxS/XHvaY3dJ4y1aVGHn9kj7SYcx1nZUVVWrRl1p7xYRVrcfg@TzcJNRiMEKrxAOc1oVzuxOSGjcwTBp4u2w5u@1w6n0ITbKPteW5fu8rXC@bVEOcXtmwW4TvxuItb8PstInToxcyfnyUmddvTObiR/ABZy/PHHlyNNjUW2agljZbomulJck8rqQsUHKvVcKmNaUXF8A4OQ1@KZq71JVLMM/NNYE/Rnh5SiIiJFzWpN7xToB/m0Y3FxBwPLCnt0DyBlPPULWvlfoK6NXmquvVvoOT0gDqxb6096AV241GhNr3Jd/4oFGxgxt4c1y3vG/v7CYcnzYnZFfS84ZtisQgnOE035FOLhDccnBL7QSFZugCbeGFw@/fh@2YBVXFogcgEG@Yw0wuDLomaMB8MryQaBXCgoiiNownwCY4mxrTexMI9wJ7Tx6ucX0MpKR542oqvcfr2cvv7BjMfgwTxvA31GR1E/z6rzrgvRvRbV7YMGoq5b0a1oYbepMw1OSIPEjrwqGOvpDEw3jfrVws4@Nja/uos8Rm4PBfkcPGZr9EzxNQ7r9sNsupDMOy2l1PyOjRZYX8/XqEoRXCVUCZPyOGLs8q78buxEM4oAtyCrpfvBlcMDifg@tkiv2UaegOcpKWxjp16V9W7QTp1/kuKGJO6vIZurqnUBZ73XKVoiUrxEfrjYCVgBqH9pNI9d5BuMZ2mC9MaqN9SRV@E0atSVtXldjDsKbvUZVzmSCeKZMQvjNDs8dIg6nx0878Gfj9NXUe2g@dy/PSbh5d7sqC4JW7q012pAxoWBYbGCSF6nlbjvgynU3/9f7Buw3KAx41s47VPYmP@xuL9MMZ4zCx1M@p0aHqJJX7buBoz4FhU5kp8SwGk0QM79H5DrIL0aidclQAruGpTn/RbCUTO1y@yanU86vywShD@pT46Zgbq6Uf0xLWJ/8jRtN4fcxzvSJ6xGQ4XKGblDipcooLjPG9t/XabrlQq6tlgbU1VKjv0kcupyk5F7SFhZ0ft0e8d/H6xtf7mTVluzu1lvlLijkm8VzsEg5egNdoI7NFPytvCjgpbKQzxs8LWs2z52eXW5nY5LJxXdi4KhSv6@ud//vc//@t/ChX943/xY4d/nP9iC@Xz@cKz1tdnL@7L@H2@d7H6rHn@bHCxelUGl/0f)

[Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) is an object-oriented extension of ALGOL.
Simula does not allow most of non-whitespace controls ([link](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Esimula/Standard/CharSet.html)).
Before this addition polyglot had only one such character - ESC for V. To get rid of it
I used V [verbose mode](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Verbose-mode) in which `<esc>` can be used instead of literal ESC character.

[Cim](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Cim) Simula compiler (installed on tio) has preprocessor. I used `#comment` and `#endcomment` to hide the bulk of polyglot and `#nocomment` to insert
Simula code on a line starting with `#`. Invalid preprocessor directives are ignored.

Line 5:

```
#comment af ...
```

Lines 153/154:

```
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
```

To fix evil: removed `a` before `f` on the first line, added `af` after `#comment`. Removing `a` from the first line breaks Beatnik, so I just swapped `a` and `f`.
Capital `O`s are for ADJUST.

Line 157:

```
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  ...
```

Separated Retina from V. Two spaces before `<esc>` are for Pip, third space is to fix Archway. `//` after `<esc>` is for V.
Two `e`s in `<esc>`s are compensated by removing two `e`s from Paintfuck. Two `s`s are compensated in alphuck by removing `s`s from lines 156/157
(previously 154/155). One of these `s`s is skipped by Paintfuck, so we still need to add one `n` to fix it.
Two `<`s are compensated with two `}<}` in BitChanger.

Removed `$`, `''` and string of `{`s from line 157. Small refactoring: `2` + `3` → `5` for l33t on the first line.

Comment: That's not just "an object-oriented extension of ALGOL", that's the oldest OO language, period!

Comment: `#comment af ...` well that's a pretty good description of this polyglot

Answer (score 11):

## 170. Haskell with NegativeLiterals, 8944 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<

>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=9717 96lo
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/

>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W<p
>instance Eq B where{-[ppWWWWWWWWWWWWay Uce stagehere]-}(B a  )==  (B b)=a==b
>instance Num B where{ fromInteger=B;negate  ( B a             )=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$169+1:[128|B 2==head  [(-1 )::B]]--}


#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#p>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#v>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001820 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9100 bytes)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkhj4uVL3D@5LMMEqZBJA4sE3QLAKfHWxu6rIIVlV3QOiWIlEAshiIhOdCZBAsdi2qzsb7UN2J82O1kazp@2ZPZ3dmp0@rEk6M8l2zc7s9FW2P6L349rZzT@Yc/eIfOFBsmZ2TQcSyMh4eHh4eHh4RHhENHW/@5vfpPDDjl173LHdARuY/oC1POvK9DS2M2bPdMtfLS1LEsaqeZ1hz3QGfllKsSJjlmNYLXhnA/fSdKyPpgf@Jcb6ntvx9B4bdPUBM31D75s@c4eD/nDA3PbsZMuM7ffcD1YOU/YspwPRBqbX98wBha8w9tqx9V6zpU@ErE5k2Pcg3Gd7pv2p92nADLfX052WDzHXGHvper6J8Q3T911Mvs7YaN80JoBuQFTds9wXtVdfTARtMvYFoKj3bXPE9KY/8HRjYLkO0qTATl@9Pj2eSFEssjdnBweTviX2Vc512MHQuJwMWmavPV@39Un4K6w2HLiHg4Q/1c2x57aGBtJt0DUBHNK6bdmmLxlAk23WFzWsoYOlmGfqLR5NarsewySsd2kzixn9PmvaelczmG1B3IPCBjOxathHCLe7Phv1e8y3egDFd3tmHHefOabZYn7fNKy2ZRAGzBwNTMcHTH2NWVDWa8u2Wcu0IUGElpEFYGzox7w4EprUciUGH6M/UYjwbdGEOI4ZEMLsQ80hIVysaKBKQI9rT@/3AUmg5CkgPrB6wJfWIO0zU/ct5HxI4ptOi2jYD9uEy3QnXkp2ZUHNAL5Dj2D7pocVoRFc1jU9E0DqIVcq1541ABIgiWvs2NQ9duaZpppsH4ksITMXcxhgQTSqwq2t9P7RQRqqkqfQ9P5ASnnLZz/6UtKZVmWLFxX4VmW5Iu2/2mM3i@fo5s0BqrvvKbrKqt8xP39@bsJ3VGzmO96tBFAloIrN8m5/kNdzfUAwNwAE8zo60ZW7Kml9O5Yx25qoixiD8VgtqA126LA3WSqZMfQ8bPIRUfVLKLTtOh2gJxTWGzpID4etFaAKDBdabJaZV0A1aCJUR@41Ufisa0Gl@VglsUbABRcRFEQX8J6gaJCv79pDigcp/QEyIFAFkiLEwzZ7w9q6ZWMSCEdQHGvP9If2ANMMnRbWPAgms6WxAA3DbWGknnsF2ekAlDygPfVirZCQgshQES4VFYN@@Bd/1up0AE7NMFyvJdj1DWu5BolYnZAFucWQYV1HtwktiJfF3HlyyOBKt62WPsDsnbHIgpCgXK/dod1iLmToXVvQtLr6FTTHdts0BiZnci6Vs6ynX3LZYXHOhYL39CZULGVAeVOxc@zZLtSSYUop4plcbzhob7Bcf5@l/fw75WlZebpwbgJyqqYuLebznQownLZEXvCWvotz3tQS0s4f6L5rtaT@eNB1nRLLGUw2qm7fdJR0AkY6m/aaaVVDmaaoFatqaG3LaSnpLeDFbcg4rVaMqlG3yo3KRPJ4lgDmGsFgczUVQ5UlEDnUKK7yPd1ytP6YvckJVyzM9S@Q5BisxbyRMJN@V9wjRb0S8qWLDAJySPNt0@wrBa2oopjAeDPLjQGzSjoBQxS4bDUy6VQ6Ey86QYCSJgqKjfXMclFs2f0udkhAFMfvg/j2kHcNHbjHRyk@ANUgy5rE1yT6QbKQTLw2057JmiBIAz6iJsmbHKbPoaAUEKImlGzJZivWkEEIQFse@FPS2HavIUPCCfsuEB0OZqp3oGogMS9IjReE50Q@ySJdOiBQEFrTZBu5pgWNAJsbyHTB87GyQfTlEo8D0Hgjicmenj4GKAbvC6MGw6w2tKUeiAdvzAwTZQ4IH5N3KJjJkNqfD8oQqkWFXGl1NdnGpprYwMvXcj8GIf0xf2dLwsLXEioC9Dxt85rZutMZ6h3UxxxIohuG2R8IQQUl8Qcgiib7G/LMic5T87vS4rPJvKkTEd1qLA8U8rz2RFeoo3QRGlnOBmHKdKFTspblgViyx5O5Q4Sriczl9xglgcB7eQ4KgQYATGaOTGM4AKkGDHzdtYwu8Cxi53C5yDuhyezBK547SPZcO8wakSluPylJWj70QjTmgshhjU7Dgc4VQW0nPKjy4x53Q9b93gzAbogidAQxXy2va8B798DsuY47AygQMgSLUZIhvB5AEztFLRA6rkDtosYaqoZhFUGdgdSAlg/81x0M@n4Z@glr0B02NeCU/Jk3PhwcOcgs@YE3tgYudzdttwli2Yf2mQ9yyBvDpjWaKBD5hXX4wZeuQAFr@6wKPfe3Q@A6Jd32QWCS/y5GjgXJJLgJBP@VISJF0oBQStsnUXwAQuV07BiKrFFT0qDRyVkmY8OVVXBgqpAuu24PpRB7S4oBano7HkiuNkgrIfNJ5Oszu7pQ9pNel05rH1zLUW7SCwsL6XJ6GyT7wsJTcG2h6ym6MuB6Sq4cuTCehi5KkSUXhtYpBfo10rf1APJIbWC1jbBX@mj1Fb1eLi83snq9KJ4lfKog6kCyQewcPgBOWq1W0amq8vY1FFRrtpOl30XpfGp4Vl8Q4Uv9SufvggrLRAar13c9VGAr2MneTZNe1YNeEJRWo6t46fN64bxxfnPeypzfprOYWq3o1SYUCvJTelrHc4fQXar1lXKu2FDV@jJ0ks1qupBeUpSNnA0Z6ar6eEPN6JzaStoEqa2cn6eBqII@daPrEbxRtqSqIakAD@yYQSdU0trNBuTfVBtqJg1p1XQWhhjVdBooYyARfCo0ciYR6AAYcPf0RWJI2LsE8cgM30ZdIudxdQJe80vcs0WPUGUqs0NSOR3oLwEF6C5b4dDGcZ2cMyQFmLRTN54RDcIwBvlh54GC0UrEQcBtawQaPjTccaDJYAeMyswuDPNc29Tekm4hM@B8hu1Vm6nOHPN@QTP8qBJBcQFn39YNaJlJcOcyOweAwKj5/OwQtTIFeFLXoWHJfWWEnsHQHaRfyyK1e2j5XSQvqEY4FvDaQFXUuaFzN4lqh8yATrsDlDZH1oAr4cAIp5jkue4rKqp9Na42obaGXT4iFQzZqT92DRiwmND1Yygf/bF958ryXAeJrO0DaODYCtbBBPBZ5AU2qtUOS3vz6TsLOFBsyrsYo20c6iRxDd9gece13Y7LliACsqamccY@dAxAAZS2AYwPmW99JALVOi6MXJI8aGJ/7aOSV1xbDtVnHWPmKb72AYQFm13oKMKcMp8e/ngfRHxxtVAA/IO3An3CQsagTJYRPQ0WRRDNFpr@WXdoSqbRdZl8Dh1kaZvlW@ZVHpubDD1RFzS9HGhTpke6RJhMTFVJA3cISknLtK2eNTikuRnbwZ436lWC0F1grwjAsWUOJKEuR50xTtNEgtLp8Pj7I5SnvmTSk7062tu/OK6dPa/K@aHv5W2rCfXXMi96oDfZpi8zlmInJqQWCT5e2ieuO6hSleCM0PQnhZGC@C/2Ll4c7pzUTr7h2VA63@oNbR0z4/FP6T1gk9h0Uttze6GO6AvaLi4jNc3EdCEOmEToCoYOxWRhzH8N/Xs4AagZUscwWM7lr6GniLiOEXFSUDP6famTyWBMmiQMPUXMDQKJE4Wa1ww8N9EznCKMqeFxcLPC5ycSkG@KhVsE7jtDvx8r2U2xSP5Xg3Yb@5HQu0TelzkAAwpk6L1M3nyKMZFVQJapoJmRQ3grBI9PTc6ENxU0MzKv/zMQhi9cEHwvLJ/mi@MMIYU97LkkB2pCQhuQo5BSNFxnuavZ8wxyHBDxJnDTpYvaaeS6gDH1KkIJQfQu7emUbegj6CcRdQqp6RDeJnrNNv3MiFAWQ1ho4DiRilT5EqfhcJTtQo9tXlM0UsYJGFDLcvT8CT1QLZ@FT3KAkUCmabaH0JnlQVtC9z3RcpsbFLPdbFrzogJdEPXgOSOaN2zOIhsMDrpTY1CWIPxg6A1ssyWe//X3WlAB09XT1cfUgYeOC6Ab8UZ7bm2JpPhCP7NrluJ8GNqWTmQg130gDR2n/XQ7dMwGjbKY5XJd3ethPykqF5gTf6Ct38FnHHPPtIctM3jOzoRInBzp8tSO1aMSwRMVPVLc5ySfGKfz9KQq2a7eIihcobHMqLZ5vZgj3rXHlAAQpw/AMxhOs2j@GsaNgyH/xSnr@@rV6uN3NlXKSSYrrOrNopl3fb1pmXfwgadfDlturn/ZoUIjamvzuJ03Ihz95dq2fsmdF@icTQBeRM/qdGDUK57zol13QWHx@6Dy5K/pcQerBB0Ko15fvwumZ/PfeVGC1b3QMZ9Olk0/n8OQxCIGtBokLS4m5WJksiYIa@vNMY7bup/PWZgh9dQgeKpGJlNYxm4snISMlq36/fnpse@j9Jubs1PzFS4CYLjttmne15qhR7J6up0rtWLOucI5mFWIXDOikiadM2zdByYZCDKbV1At9HMX42InYyC7RK472DZCJ5hjnjddGaXpW4ZrW36ftyTxMk9KTk70RGBwHZN@oqT4Nk3fFgwXsAPPha7ZDd01BjhlOIePHiC4@GwdzofGGENz59HOcK/xO1d16LpXJv@d3Zl9nInVA0RQzibOsIwZyVvGfeyKi070M5uKlzOxGhj2TP8ye@m6Xtd0fFbSCsH0Bs7467bNpw/PDo/m87Rv2a4PIw38vYsWMKLwff47m5vjZLN0J0eTOHH37GQCqT7TxJh3TmXqdse11zY6eR1@5tb40GujZBfPh0q0UCIVi/dKpFDxcZ2ieM4V5Zfwfx8z0ESRhzPCMecd/egs8SVmEucXEIYHuMwzu3AHhQ1KqeX5sG9eBXhG91ofB8/foreYR92gt@iPSW0GvQ4TbG6AY@BxVfq3yW3l7txaD5NJU2DX7ytErHIvbRMkNP1OVSkrFYqfmaJYKDxcQrXtoTk0Z0qMo@YHE61r7pAVD0eqIIqxKKZA8kA8nAAJY30Ug8IHYY39N77dKWB024JGfq/2MlPe9UHX7uM4@hgcx@iYTthxhv1E5cZodzJ0Tu6mXLcftGy3lUASQz5XIm3cryMl1HHfpO881X2/58LQ1@2BzuA8oP4FUJpT4r8JwOQTQf5g4fybdyfcMguXjkBfBf0DatW69HM4ifcwwVOaN2anyJubMCpzzMEYf@dRe5Ygbbqu/Tm1A/K0ZaFaBsom2obdV0tTuo5YRWTR7ISPMx3N9rx5Cd7XiAEkUA8Hy3Mr@hiKNKDO4SG1PDVpeEevFZtCvG8cCT02Tf74nhG45@F7go27qG1o63cizNVRt2naOn@M1lbugrepLT9EJeoHei7NIuPMM59rjlY@UhMiqD8GYlmtnG90zZ5Jr3co@Xrrw9APHnMjjVz8zgjW8jTNOidd34I27@BvYl47phUNXMf08wPd65g4PLFxuUH4zpOzweztTOIe9vSOeXAvc0WzD2hiQst5MefseYgyX/U1INk9koSP/Fzn0hz7wXO2fjw2oD6HvTuhzWrnBk5y3tuwtfzMSet71D6n63adrtn1qHGEb/OaB3DkgJvW3lUIwL@r@5doU0MyKRrWdf04dW3Xth9CXZSJXEK67uz51300Ym1B0s@CO9abECAe907VQddNRKI@fF7b6ZpD6KF8d@D2zRy9zYtq46QO/509pXx4lPbZW8v0Wnw9EWf49IHVtE12bQEKH/z4utzsCaOm7epotnWHEg@UCZ4PmYIyXO@@XqGju4N@nx4XfXvo0w/N5Obas6coy@yAEH0IL1gDvpLLOdbsuE2ja91XeU1THzjWZV60fvE6m8uTspgKbrHcHnprtgWk8sYa8kA1Hn6Kj8PZ7d56IQzj79RHdoeeN75fNiRXKcNZVb4WgI558y9i9WlGMPX8aK4QLMvfsSAhFqvmMhTp0qg358wCKCfFubNBCdMKQQJ7eXlwD5UM17i8V52YOz8pFjaRVIYVW34F/8lJjLvReC7EGwwOlefDjq/eF3@Mqtae1eOm9rodGRXdk7LW4ZyDC0m@7V7HJppBJOiOeMzkvNKL@9sTrYas3rkwUmbFFxe1o8P7gRm21ff5L8u1SzNViOnFy1k5foNVeDdlTqEltB8@eOi5HtqhgraRMzzTN3ASHAU1F6BcPDluBwR2zmZR5CDuzLJML5zOUmOSnWHu61dmR0ezlhcWWrjY/lT/yFdaT8jmPrTO9LNiswD4WZ4wDffD/Rcpst8gW83Ado@l0IJ0iCw/cD2NUTxF0TMZVZV4Ipw87DgQLYhFFvBoHcuN631mW/6A4lptVq@zxZtRuVAu3rIqk8syazQ4VLLT3B/1yXT9hCetL@qN6mI6l0svps@dMiukKapp@@bsqHoiXtuiB8czKjpzdG6dg@6gpBVu9et3yaIeuocWdDOvYXBCosb1uO0qN4w@w1XI//KXLbHRAFRRn/Us4EkgBG6OcXtm171@yvMVudf6fR03KiCM6y72YZh7brfG/Gvsj/j@AveavT442xBWy2ILD7wco@CMYcErFcdFaLI04JXGsWm5JudnkXGYKiiU4drDngMKQGvQ9TVoA2SNNPQiKwxwYTRn4KEW1MqyQ9Yyca2HjMxI8bdd95LMPRGT//KX3FabTM2ECVCQPe3RiOWIFmVFMpA2DHcIWAdAPpqeK6IoSGRoDUMcVkNrNLm/igZYZEQOnJgLTKgxG25GvVs7Zbl9lsY9RmiYWbHaymLt5Is39UKj@h3r5c3/@nt59UbQTX6c21zz5SwLolRuka/iwasQHIWmmbw4kkWxcDcLbd4ImUpsf1PQTdUVmET3aCMM8Z15TSbRZMjjYGPHHSYgzn1QPQcqgeaNprqoDPkALnc6YKu4EQvGRDq4@NYZMjBD815Msjhin1gXeSVnoNETvHGC2GhR3qvuBGv4y3FLi/ye2RzS8uJVSSstV6k4ixfVrW1yeWbLxZ0d9Xfno1Ihdz5a32/k/YA45@ejx4XS10A9F3TLxSd5bED7r/ZuFrXtwqdPvj5msnybrnADEmjlizfHh8f7p2e1s9enQM1bXtjUgev19EhSIC@QDVfXtWnLDJDFs0z/fukRSpDwDaIrClvU2Rbu2lNVKW7ARFEFqeWcvMidYRQYZMVT35N8VnrfjIVPRxCSqW0xIUXZMTGS4Jm0H5eg2YC3sF6wuYMqHFIEzXNmiEKikcyqQKUcUOmBNGLTpeQ1@JQ8oBrvJ9TdMGaBAFpFMaYjIJHCvLC8PJwXbmbhb/8BStyHfu13LTHBuLPEGOOuEkPEKBmlOKgdvnh9sp9MBOwU7Y@EgayHW2jb1Lb4TivOXa7Y1BNIJhoD@sKIP5StPruyfBojIr@1sWewQbhgcyQrAx@lCzf5ZTXbB0neaoFoao4HKNlApGtkN8aNx3IOk1NALC3saLNMljCuX53e5AGS69oAKfaeJ16keATZl2bsRjs38z/8iz/jO9DOB@D@Q@EeFXbg7Y/FWxvc/zwIKRbh7V@GbyV4@yl/e5dHUk5vu@GlCYmIBHxzeMx8GsYiiXr6KFZ67Nuw77QcGEhZPaD1FZEOo/NiRZSJ4Cj1N0B5qC4gOwpplMuUn@k1FNw0Uc7nURXBuUeNbJvMER/E0h6Kb4e4dxC6kvza6tpKEUZxZu4qAEh20B00puEAVbUMXCldWf3q@6bBtra2mOwbum1W1yqc5PlF/d2y/D5EdBHiSlxrqTNIA0miFBC2LZIpi3qmqGJSbJzpYpo1KqCQ8BqEPk0hB0RR0dsJTGmh03QFqYA9HHM0IME/DrQxUIUcsuQ0@Q7SAFAOAHHYuMNtkssj8xi0JozxvRavBvktRjvFaGV5FpPV37HzwbnTEDsdGTDML2ewnAPuP5qx/THkntr0vjtlctccloY9O3VcNKM6AGyZUsqXlvPFNTXWpmQBCvDFFvQJQEKbgTZomNYHt@/XdvcPvzw6Pp3aP0Yx05PR0iy9vZU5z2nZeiN0pCe4PiDqzkH@9OXOQUDKOFbRKgTGiJYiJtGcldskpnNyf8vtkqbzpoCpjIqFhwKmoXTugFbrpqFHoflYxF1uNzGVq6Le3NYbW9vnTmoq@0@z9tSmtCVkLnCd@7SjNs1myJzDwNrqDA9V8LXAOLckRzvGQ3Nc/h55z98BFh7REG0DC@y6JLJwDw3cJW2OxReUXcvzrGgPFEcswBdkTYBqEVGNMjSkqZWkODZMlGX6NAlhmRwS6YgPZGlrq@7AGMazDB7bJwHNh7u0HxMGPIeDaIwE4y6cPqGh4JiGPSAqwgmclkUjct0L7LDDkFOzZ@XOAnxQcETbusR@Jhixd22rWdGr9RELjZrv2t2k@X3bGii41Wqk4XASSqOoWIDiFu5VGqlbmw2xLYwFu7cytAHseAj0Onb7LBrC75mB6wRGcWxvCMCBDUz25bAH8dr0ODGxlzDZKzcHiYGO6QCJOm55EmXQeq1VyF3rmqOW1YGeRlGzIJIeF4vR1jEd9z45aZDDnFRfoHlNnDCftd0tRjG9rmuW0zJHCu7SKDeQOuCfvn57lVblKR6gPXdiC1prcvNdICz0gWi10ca1CYGwuRkKgmTb2dzUur6ERucwAoEcTwfeC3BCH6q0e3qfKUPavegzjdGrcq44WX/gqSy3jf3ZNXNYJkNjF3hQgMYoZZtclo1z2Apu9lfyVahn9PWdFj4@Wn1WL2paA9yUicoWcfZhF9QNHLerEqimkKRMYKEDhr8yYnQNozTEiD8XKVuJ9h9BrJnB1JA7XWqAQAsqNdt@Em13ibVATtXNzbKojaQ43GTAFlszJAaAnSHmAt0U6CvMhoFqKMQg1i4MSi0QKM@@Mh0H2qsCPNOD1sn0ITCZp2aD02yy0SEGlEOKo/hc2CEDosnDDfbTN7YL@sxivkIj4Mot9Pvvz7Hjb4uuf5z/7/NavnKjLNrVcR6UMXVbWexWi5nlpUxm0VlSFh1UR548wYHz7SJoOxearMkjiJRbtNUK8DNoR9VFp7KobymLrWppiVLAayaj3kCC7/y8drOo3@YXn4A2kQUfj7dOZdGnfYcFTSveAn7YQhbzWeCZG9x/R2fUYPaLViaDOGiLF4jAd/nz0wz1K@eneRqjV4SSm@/0AjGS1FXCmpg6W4cTUHiXQ4m@ihJdrDVfBJHjRxvMCLtTu/4KLXMYrSKYvh/nr2TIwwWLEGgonISQUfjGTyDgSAEi4mtWV1UQJr/5Taq4BqO@p2vLipt5ulqoZNKrxUo6xVLP5PyS7Mk353u5K2bm0vW2vqp92zi@PD7@Wj1X2CZLp3aP5OKK/I5tlpbyUiq/VPi0ns@/f/8e1GFW39a2tYZaz6UbdYUP6NbZ9vr6UnZtYyn7LH0RjSDXmaqUSipU2jlbZefrur6UWSk9cyoQsomfZVYEJ/5uwLfIVlfZPn7@9j/@7c//9mf093P6/rVlWX2/1YKv22WX7CN8LtsM/8n9sRVz6@hutj8qMM4A9bNKTaN4nE6vLqdP3@EO46cL8Ef/8Alf8XeBfIQ3RZn@LEipbSP1MVUsFlNj@rtAd3EUGzzn6GU075MvFkvneILC8trCMwZUNUGI4qdcfhbCyMvrG7LrkkcXclhlboq1jmK5jHL4kVLBGR25ut5usEEN/9hZE/9OBviXe3OJfycG/u1c4t/LJv4dn@Jf38e/H3Xpz8O/5w7@Nb/Fvxcf8e/MwD/CfqOaZYD8d9UqR5oJ5Cc/s7017SJwIZT3W@@rv9uHfc6nL6Vg0Jfa3m5kcre3de1dplIR/yAuK@EbfrgL8G3c5nJb77YzmTrhXd8WBdjKNbZ5aehXu3i3BWAzW/WtLe1ie3u0nWu8265jKW/wx/Bv8VGSoQmeL6GzOto64SD3ApjYLhj@0ecFz6V@/AJGOWfZ0lYuVTqo7WZLp693UkV4W41eMXAZX0/2a3tHryH28Yv92un@F4dv9l8fg7/fuNh@9iyjAc88A4S3G3UpNXqc2c5UB4PBxY8vljTsIDd5P7kZ4jDxuZjh4q9Sam979Dqf2wKkX1xsYgFPKLccUKPxiXGwUqqeqiuZp5mnBbtwVSheFi9fukfR/9HRCAKsUeGD6xW6hW6xBW2LFczXhXFhPCr03KNiC5wm/BV64LQK7VGhU3AKTrE4HiVAzf/vHbmDl0cuQHMh5WBUGCBggLRytHb0jMFr5@joJYBtAwof4M8qFAojwHVUuIL/gl2kz7uLAhRcxf248FYonJ9LdSa/N0FWasW0Vkhra@m01Vhd6397c1ta@7ZOqt3qZqOOW68bMsumL87r6UYllffPz/NcrMulFblCe7Nvby8u9mpntYuLPM6IjbYWM88yuWfwqW5ntsTjaaq1XXl6Xs4hDwbcmMpvPT3fXs6hey0DNVACv6185jM/EUh4bi@cS2nl@u3bt/h9e311zV3k4H7nb8NQ/HmbBy/uQi/4YNT8rPRJx2ia7RSlvtq4uYXu7TxdSYsOUGF0zoFcPB@V2qwk4yBD2VRBxyguoya7tsrU7e21VfBY21BzSgEHITzJudzv989ljaZdNLJIrVZrnqePcailrAAQZXO1Wj2Xde/iXK6XGph2Nbe5xlwvt7msyqr6rri1BXlgFiUVvOX0SHa9NLu5jf8pN7dbCn1U/FNV9FSBbei5rSoQQV2Ft9GNwraULQX9wAvT3dxuo5Pi3YCrrqgN9faW@8Gvom5xqNsqEI6BfvGP9A/9zv9//l@@Zj6oKbcpVJwdtrKqKs2xqa6sKRuZTfFXXQDCKvJyehk1orSertefLS0vra/UnzaWtCX8Klvn240ZvbMKehK05KDtVYsprFgUZ1rlRC6W5DS6U6mKIU52sN0OW96sYIeOCWX4oEtKM6jQ7a2QhaOOW93G@mdUo0xtMPX2BtiaB4JyrYj1qfPzUaEQJFJZpVldvEnpt5UU5sJu5SCJaCGUh5Ku0CKmfCMv6l692JBv5cWb5i2ORJaKKimhqyuVytIKdy8qSnFzrbRZKq2vrW0U1zdAN1krFPKsWNworWwsr26urKxtrK6BeFPVCmW4VFwScAoARzg3KhXT140KCq5KCvBQFBjzAfFT51K1aXYgeyBQP96mM6urqwv5EjxGj9f2S6OFrSX6bC/N/GyUNjJLmWf1pc1NrMQGeX5akCq4psgXMOWczEUD29gkTFK4@sGXHRaPQSMRf0t7S9xVxO/@gi/1mQNj2vUCa7k27it02@0F8OzqPmuaJgzeTNsOjg6B8aXdurZa5oJU743aDdq7Xc3Vi2urjRwwxodRmxEzSL4Jn96xbg5N83o4vDbDz67l6x8@6H36jNo//PInP/zyf/zhVz/94Vc/@eFXP//19z//CXz/Er4/5c@f/rvNVfz99ff/8n/74c9/BZ5/Dd//DN//9Ovv//Xv8S@9/w18/6@Y39@Ibywe/0oA649//f3P/uLX3//zX8D334jvLya/P/zpv@f//7f4Q@evfvjTv8Ef8fKTn0Jx//6vfon/P/urv//Pv8T///1//fu/@ld//8f/lhx/xh3/z7/5d/z3737/J3/3T//k737/@zm/P7nz9/sH@H//j@DzcDwfAuch5fpcn@9/K3x@F2pEuQAPAKf90Q//@g@AV/@Uv/0zeIP/MOgPw5dECH/5w@gFIPwvMxL90a@//5O/CN/@IBkxEQZA/hDC/jwR9oc//PL3fviL/@GHX/7ZD7/8Y2yluZXNbC2bK949bkhBxNUHxMOIaw@JBxF5lAW2IJXoiT/Cky2Qa7QkrS7j8CrHPxnu@WkR9U12/klahffMpzyeCcPyn0ToOW4AKkLo8gqFFkB9LmDoKr4GoTFUcL366bOEVs8RWfoEujAotvlYbB7xKUdU@Gc@JcQ6pqTwhRBx@EaZLYTpF2YQ5il7BsHQa1LHuYW/@AI@OzDWE0O@6vYGq0pZtlFl22wHI1bhncLRSe/Qx@LxyFVpj@3gIBW994BCfGTORtJ7HHpnKPo2j8q2JQj/Djx2OBiChqC@k8Arw3324PmdiD@SCB7@C60V3fgNAuAnw7gfvGKvQ3DEj8Rj8GAWPOLUxAE2xsN0I/xnESABJyMBITLZ@JAszCITeUnha2YqlxCfibBMFMZE55kAlWFTAO8KTHhLkwnZTCgCg7mhE8UMQmfkGISmppOEQXECZTJJgmHKZKEyUgYt45ZEpkuZJTKEWfrcj8CJMphJjjs@cXovRSWPw42wj6ASvjxBhuJGeRNEhetUtJLAimsrIWBVUujkMNBIcVbD7INSJ730OzvuSClkZTlbXJs9daDiHAjE/cYtl6vfFVfWJXjS@xAPMRPHaQFv48nU2hZ8AA9p@yaHQkDaPt0/g7CzI1YsFTRWLzRuVtZLK6srq6XltbXV9VJxZW1zZW11Y7lQLKwVVkulIqiumxub67fS9tdspLHj4x/lwD3K5fIlBMiqxdX1yrgKCclL2iZFjiuQ45sc6I6IwDlprzdotoATODc0ufcIPkx6JLFH4AUfAIyzt0ysmh0eVcTaClrYhSo6X2iRi6ubMmn0uZwvnZtOiwOX@rGPdIZnkr4CYEANh71Ag7uBy85cl05i2zGNOTF2u/xU8V3P9f3fIc6O7lzyoD0LD0QxBmHQcx23Rfs9a9CdE@N1v4d2yKb3jwZhv9cEBHHek0fYgR/Pdt1ZEdbZ6@M5pXwZmjfjsgzZN0P0k8Mvnp/Fnmf7td3n0hrbOXq1N/FYFZFW2Yv9g7PwdZ2HBklXQxDf7L94MfkqHjiOWWCr69mspmnwg88sfeipLb4LohS1@XqFvFYorcvF7MXYhMHMTS5327GaZnENRq4r8pMUjKHwRLtTfmbfwGmxUZvYfnO9uM4212xXeokWKptFblps@WhDCZCuHTJhbeJpwMP@fE94oBc6PavTBelx7YYRfN@/vg7ni94Gk0PhJNFb1tR1/H7uB3Iw45/B3R4Dngf5TYXY09Gl5zA67OGpd7gBaYDrIlabFSQNRUWptLmxurG5XNrIbmxurKzCOHA1WyxlYTC9vlnIFgvFjSIMoTeL2Y2VzeUVEEoQurq5LqWg6VvtfB5Eb1GW6Wk5Bh5/tIXnSLlad1tKtcw28iobKS2VpVqhx3CDycsb5wUGCWUJzd6WRlW5tIIGgctFVpQlWWcGSx0c7BYODmR5B19wqnK3IMstfFndKBTWd2TZpJBdEJwlSNTFt/01nNOUZQtfdmsHBwjhA76UNhCGLF/yEP5iBy/rEM3Bl@VlBMBk@dsQXAGAuxyjDUo14C@Fws6uLA85ehvwB/Fq/G2FkN3HFwzARAc8ZBfCZPmLIBHov7J8wuOJrJ4H5a3VZPmQv9RqCOJLKvwqL9RX@FKjDyTy4A04V5Y74Oh4MPKX5SY4kX9l2QCXMdbBrwcu3HLpDHRZHvNyYElkeUSxdeNSli8Cf8gH8Hn@XO8OWmaHf8YefxoQdAhB1mi4f9D84otmp9P0xrX9L04o6Msvn@sfxkOv2WmKhM0L@LiYCoIue@PJj4lBFxe6PTvoKwhyJoIuxhcmYXihfwuYiU8HM@pdfIlBX0LQrJUsARA@PYjcxM9OD547epMHBR8Koueo2ZQryLLYdNoKMa6epQcdsqjeMDRI8BX9KYmsMoortw2qxXBDza0@HW7Ia@tyeQme8lN5GZzQNFghXWBMTp/LslrfbDyV11flcvrp01z6SfEpk9c35bK8vg6drlq5RWmnqDdtZZQdVQvgkc9vYYPGJghPUANa@kCH0cZOYMKYy71NfLa23m71pW3aaYO7Dva/hcHBNWotN7l6vx@Pqo/Za4gBETsmRmjkbpUdpgMiOFIBZ1Ot6tVqMwbt1bAXgqNzJQUW1Z2Kg/tlTNTNCEZct6ruoNHibVyHWbR1f7AI2limWK4XSxufdlipWiULe1ZXYIiqlss7jQb0ELjPRhSfy7VQMoGKAp0Rg28uJ2F4vyrqQ2YKnmSLi2q0Bq@k0@uldFpNVyDtggyUFoSmdTes0KA@ZJCIUB@bJUjumYMhdMeFyu1Uzt5lGSjioREG5VBm8hroTeCNxwNPf57BqDtbXmqubm3/k6nPf/dPZn1m@@JH4lrgWlFK3UotPMxpZVNK3Ui3N7db20GOX7HxWM8EI1v2hLFOZlFaTGPB08vJoVytWuuc1IIJ29qulMotuytuanFxUUptnW3Ly/KRdhGu0WznaenvHNcFcQ1NO7/YWsj8Vgs4OW37WbDsCajnJc/EHQktvHWFr6NsrGJFdJifyvyWH8hEqgJMqYKT33IKZYNhu0Ncw9465wXa@i5F6yzs@KY9dMgkrfwSlWRFL3N1pN4ARv7ulWXfbCzntsmSQgEOu70lrjCOaJlbSjmucAIhYXgyMEcDBXTqVVmMMUzWP918t/5u493L10evjw7Ys0J5owzj9XPgkWwxXUxDFT6DLtg62YdBzyd3tfid82UlVe6nl1fSy2GVnVdTnD7gRqZX6vVig9WXG406MFqDqfBarZaeFlc3Mitl0J7U1DZuGSmtp/pAanQW1wu55VRDwFlZV8FN8@WlYuqK1nyl1MbL9zh/EtwBYpXIlc8ztni7dQv/27esvrV1iwMi/L0VTwjj4fSPCAcv9Ig@iXhRnCj8t@Mr7SLV@C63xf@38Gf3iJdTXluV1dT76jbU9ruLdxcpKbXJ5BJVUCYvBjjQWDqoWy059Gf675Z8@Is8lkBZXArfzK0ln61uF2HQai7l8/lz9UclULw2N9c21lLSb4Bcd9iYQmhodNU2YeABInaG1VXNs17qaJHmhJZX4Hg5/IiHPT8LrnkJdDSGShqaFaKWFvcTilvMi25HSvqN/TzugUFfSUKXRVd7sTZxGi4tDWgvA1vCneK41U@VbqRHAGtoDGj7DPxUJOkR7uPAVyWIl2VP/IGKM2EFVXr0SEhYf6D5gwsEjomEZ65YkUD4A3n0VstndNw6rojy/YE67opw@/xIFXvMeCKf2gJXOGlrH@YbQ3iJtTkWUJolRjkS5lg4nv0jHq05bCMqB4cv9iENDJXbZP8kUsteEy8joOIttFUWdhRAAzyRuyooRdExIoADT65PqD3chGgoFDPDihjeJjsqiJVlxSxhkmVtkbCOrw1IjuDbILh8AMxzV3gJ2NKFyFaUQeBDhQASYumov0OH7nWMrKg9PG603lDZTbDVScFQtsVK0V4sAQsqg18gRgmNXkscrF6NyEzQio0sVG2Fb5lRwnjCJyLUrbQ0yPYqvKr6FekrxQC1x/WUyne9J0@Md/16r1FRe9UBPjOZHvTBl4rFoywNqr0qsEe/bjUqg3omYzWqPfUrBd/x/gLssIXy5quibFBypwq4oF2ar2Y/1p3cd04je1B3MoDyMLv04@rHrF4toNqVtarFrJ39tloU5YA8B9WPGaeib8EXbQkT25FA7cjolYQXJrlU7OrHut5APc6GhJnMARQG8PTrdibTUCFzGwKnE1bsJ0/0jL09qti5nIqx3i0/PagPwNHIVPG9rOhbo6cf60NIX1bgWYVsbBWQh3SC1rch7oBfBWjM6zRCneNIauYI0OtVq0s/frr046XqwsLH@ijXa2Q5@cuFiBsQ@REiX4lt91KWfqyyCZLQIrEiP7bKjzUQjnLWymSAyNl@LCXHcOnHENLPZAKsb1Fe0rVGgZ0qcpjYosTPMqeDjMnsnA6U9@lehkELN2tC2ppvWJaIznfZ9i0Y8Ot4WkCWLi3QKQaGiXvWMPB89PSpFGQtdsVAzihcmiZotK5j0m07Hq5W0519/GCE@@TrLDEcyNxwwEwH6MPQfHkt1lxJNFGD8z2jjlFQDNwUbitcYvG9UCBsSHpAHJIeGC@HUgSJJOSEiFkVgVBbQQVBKpQTbX6oBx1fgPIJleew5YMI4WhAY56BhpX9UCXZBPxkgYtZW5QfOKCpSI@gEIgDlsFqsG0QZOzJEyZet6qsWFrHvgCjYbwPmSJGmsIUMn8ApgADsfwAPIrykDIB3B5hCO71S2S08rtlJLbqKpAg8yHLd@xqtGNXGTo@36iOdFM5GlgXjx59yFRXBELwT2MPSA9ht79Jie6@zHaPXh6/Pts/eVk7hV8YaW7E7yUJ7vyauvGnjzf5NC2H9qsZ@knR/OZLA0ZkONbCU4nxSr8W@/L1C1YqvdrL4pmCQPoUn9yGDrUcQjJ9OrPd11yvk7@2Lq188mJRvH2NtsbRNaa54AITRIc6ZzvaPh/tnvdx1g46c3EQWuKukJ7p@@Iio1xwKSQdQ0MHCfRwPzy0QnHxEe06CAynyUwfLSSytPnDszoW3fTX5QAS6ekKiAFPTu1DwguLaEgNHC1tbhQKZVbIoqMYOEqBYzlwrASO1cCxFjjWA8dG4NgUjmIAucghw5h3eXktcq5Hzo3IuRk6VwqRM4KwUoqcy5FzJXKuRs4ot5Uwt7UNgstSATWp6ZoehhVXNoIwGv8PyHMVwBQnPVcA0dJUTEi@MuUJ@W0kPdc3CyKjw/wRRiqV1qJ3kD5B3KrCscpyPLI8Z/4mPKGvkvhIjhh23/NAKu2P8IY2YDq1zHA7sCThmSSGbeqgDJgD0FKqB8D/plrmx2R443K0JRghVIvhOyTHC0IgTZEuGeTsMyO4NCuYQyvNhMYPSGEhYWL7qQWSHMtyoqflEFcSfnGoCyhgkaJzYpR4DKyD5AbsIM8zbzgzy@W7s0wAnJnlFFIc7uqsVEgbhYBXg6TU/xO0apAf11NMqm1QA8SVssQDExWK56VUb4pl@dff/@L/YL/@/me/Yj/8@a/@3//0P6P73@PPfwCdhZXCCD/9GSNbDvj5V4wsN8iKJEpE8ZfL8g@/@CW8/k//lv3wk5/xoD/5Czm7EgKCEPSKUv78n@HPH@DP/ylnV8OIP/8jHhGTyNlbKaFaKRDrp3/NGOSGUEJgv/hLxuQMKBiK4Lw6b@ON2OkKHEBIhjq5GpPh/Bcv5gIaF9SMDHDFWzF6y2AFqDHgno53pEZtD9QZvuqIUtrQjS7uoBdero/6j4EqjOtrHeC36xYoPWJCIg2l/31WZukMxsG5EzwmpspluCi/KLcchWLcjJwH7PByHwGKri0LMYHhrQT8TSOBsa/hsIVGpEXOI4K@r/AO5qADkQPOolucJJFXkBpnXsSNlnStVzDURabFbogfs0K3WUlii3cxlmFC3ExUG@Qy6QNDxujghXhS8jB7fagSSBbSGwmLL0SF7CS4qOZEs9k/OphoMPhpgop5GZdIYUZVJsv3xEVKi/gqalzLyfgcXxGhXigvNxLHOMyKLH/99deyFPMrIA95LYUgxArFRUYYVEwGlWJBpVgQ4MxhkqxZLZUmcKCOA@Vi8sgSniwmopLJIubClhPUA6IBY0E@55lt20O/W50GTRI5KeymgcdAFhtV0U7OHZI520xWpxIAzGSa6mRdzgZdmIozXVGzUyK1Ez6J2poPKZEm1iiIetIklcKaK27OqrlkhneALjYyD8yoVPgdM8o9MKO11fszmqxWTJsAP5@@94udQEyEEj4Cxht@KtFBYdf4C2C9SBwhxh45FRWGPDUx5Gleu0yZcXUp@OeDQ4QT95V6saOFcRDzyh2YfHrgWd@FIYeLWnDseuTXInpi2MHvFe84rmf68eNZLL6B3UnjAUGG23GgV8viYcaWuIwXzQj4GXbJfiXs2YQWusvvTkfQnFCoeV5cWI41uLgA5dNuqxEB8VUzcFdxWsJL18EVS6@Equ1RX3HxUPaBej9M0nd5sjPLuFSO@iIwDZnUGAzoDNOGwRfr4rWMvstJgkXkFzWCRtocKHRyYtftuR3TcfFsJEw9Af4wgo0I6f0@4ZJlepYZMYzEIFoxsroqkn712UnZVyW8WDRIX0oCSBAjy7xJGiNlvRnZXczNjicL8jv9fHxP4/ie3o1v2/L8wSTO5ImzPfj8vKyXlQgCRIzQWL4fjaw4Dm0KnQQqoTdeCcwTPBjFFpk2tRDTGkStiehaG/gjG775tH9YIP5mHv3vrsAg@f5Dq4@U2dMxyJse3eBJQzQ/WA1XIPqhqka2ibHsQtbee2BeYqBDI7wsk0lwObg5HRpmv286eIkk/wSA7@F5tG@a4nsyeqrywBk4eVdZdlmaX0V7Fy3T1sdmSxExszG4QYlPTL1F8uphBUdBR0LP5fdAK4VsMaGK0SEiFKk8h2X07JWqzmcrHsUKuYcW4wjDw/n0o4m7SdGMk6BVvgbieiBBU3TOIJ3u2B/3x/zgIZtOBAvkKO9/eE2@wvOY7iUI0IHfk1rMRtmqd4nPEyUs0gN6hDCuliwybd8Pui0XtPGpOvw8Et1fUpplCBNVg1pOaCfzaty6q8ZjXBHwJNdKHsaS9zHdg3kuxmocWCTCdj@vC5mCvKvbtmEocYjc584ac50pmYB@WGOuM6dXuZghUMOUJOkGeIlclesXqmSB8xCeV/B8A08ECGPQC85QQdlQrw2mvCikp/djWovwqRuoi8aoqMbXEWOxpMCNE7m3YZ7G3DyNqTyNRJ5hC0hmGYskGYksRS1g9dxVBbbZHsyRzhiEI3d43CW24eO4uodrrzdpK122six9lS6DQE6b6fK@AkI53UqX98jhp8un5LhMl78CR9S20p/S5aBZYAQPXsnxDP2FCMd3I13eVdRbaYCHrAb5aulyWKcQ5yl/JYrc8unVplj1d8NZVRMv@UalMsuQY3x4uFiseiNL3wL8U1RxeC8ELlRZaYki4wAk0WnEegyeD3QbGl7T7imzuo9yMDUl5jeiORQIz1RjkyrIJUOSR@lUOimMOGIYSpOP8AQEUW6WZ2PEilMjs/vQEblbeL06EDuZP1FPI32gpVB4HSLHJ3HsKH1QX0kQvAIfhicmnofnFDpBdoQRGgOoM9BCor5P31EorOuJg2B57cdraHqOACsxF0ThtURgYzIddDjUTSmzvttPMgmF4mqfFU@DH9EokXsnkpFUEC1zTjB5i5KhYIg3fvWu4sTSIWoJEYSB9UKDt7KwXyBZjEGRrItpqrzxAQoxmdOik9lMZNs94aR4XNxkqa@Y1w0FaXmWJLmSYhISa3iawVAf8NyjdRk84@Dzhq9ByhEexa4ggFjKMBcuX93P0N9drr8HCnVAhIkMZinWs7vSafX6zl52AnM7yna6AjEwy/bUmcpRmENEchgdxDTzu3htSsXH@4a5ks8zDaFPaPsB2cIxwT10mxxbcFioJXhXSc9LnJi9LM0n1LRGYl9pgdKiYU4CDi94iGlUtLtx5QWfVcUYgn00PD67gr1kBccrD@FRAbwJkvNW7g0dMq@K2jadrxWtXPBVBxetxMJjjWOeIO7Jfi000QKPo4uTvaNXL76BTnd9fV2dXorAVgtpo35cunOZIBy2lLJ4MiUepk22E13XGyycO/K0SRl5gDKg07oNZz/RxlUhy2LyfKLtQjoeN0ZRAesyagZ6QiqhqqNjl20JuvJLrpQlXQAJ1Fugd5ZGa7hqhNyBCzoXF9R9XVygcc7FhejFsGrCZaTfpMR116XIXgNcCWsm0rj8qePfcAJg2KN9T8EEnDjYjduhpADO4SBIHaYaOgMrMHbA@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@MFRc4AlIysyglIEF@sfjziknc6KQhFEA@fa4ptep5D0aQrECWMrtwVZsSVOwx7ybIXzQcTdr04mIobaraF/Rq/pyorv0YLrDLPhPoODc9uRdFdmZTduWJgrkkPtJNmS7SnuJ3oaGQPE4doLFjOXQhQj0IcinKGzL8e@2X4Ag7ZACSQiSwWFKKNei9uRBG0o8aTKAqNSqxLUYpxbBDBtg8CpQ30zMqP0Wr1CSSkLhb6O3WW2lSoJNIDcn7fIUtuOafJlFRYHSOkJAhem@gf2r5KZPAeCK47TqPX88WNwtom2U8zJzvI9uqbjeySUZWZObB0p@cPvevWZcftXoGywPofmiNj/PFbxlZXGO4iKT3hu@2La9U8bahfpxMpNulIp8XguAs6s@FcZoz29OLpGmnGwj1FlQXcZg@fLP6U5coUl7KlXsCF3Ii6V19rVJ1qodKrO42Kk8mog0x1kClmFPR4UlQrIGn5tEt90CCryPwSexmYLuJZrTi36rbZsesYXTftM7rsMr6mRxvFggbU0/vx9nQFow7Xi/u0kZ/0XqIhTnvRHVATKS03iDcY900UjaHVp403BePPo@HaSmU6HEv46BGaKFeEbhovwI3UHzZtywAZRPREFQPNFctlYXRvMORbEFDoZ3FPjgv0QAoGV4JQw@2PRWKLR7kIyrIVA7mtYN@lZh8SM4jVBJ68wJP1PYjGo3DyJqIzAE1dj8qxQvcL0wn7GdwnoVbQipwtBGHBjgqMj3xD@xouQP2jXRDw2GIiKtkYM1VY9JJv3UKjAlLVttM86NGHYa9P/bvG8RUUwWuDLvq65YUpNX@I14QprIjEsAKksQbQcYtb765AsYxXTVAXOLFAi9tYHoR3TGc/A8KGjpcGgmzExR2E13IpzSN@L5UCnSCfuOJoiLRUDFVUNRAOT05L99NlRvMMFfCiLqcSC/0AoVjWOcE9CO7pg@6c4C7CHvrzgj0Ixtuq5gRbEMxtTmaHuxDONak5EQY4iwbsejFwLwa6ZSvcYBpNrW@5wFZYJhMQNmQBxiuG10cyPROm52yB1w5ntgR7QfsktuIRkKUV0XjwPeIWCsWzNhTOF7E8OU3YDbs3MzH5BCS@oJxA7GL@6lICPoshAO0PRCmbDg8y57UdFjTBPxp0Ox2sbSDWMvv06S7MBCMm@a/YCLiP1xDOc8ZKyKkVweGX6UT1yhN9FIlmpxGm@XHpFuigUTmCRlmKRAhvW1G7blugL0JSFbWcyBuHlCp7GvnU/QYrh9IjoiNvFvfTsTTFPTjipBaZZc3IaTycqjryPaTUoUduRsIC92HplSly@mHsXDL2NsQOqTnBZ0aCZ0Qr/dzCPqw0KcCPGjXRpsIFrQGq4bZAcAZ6Oq/XuEzgwBbTZe6PV/9YSWDWHGB8v@IFABhsAQ7YswViPOgTLUfjNj8g5wullSxN4fMotxGZAmH1EDr9AzQuJJzosod4G0JSJLEZpJmKHpYb6bU92eQmiscl/ezC1bnRWPppGnFk0/xEXPcUeskyK7BwY0yF3d4vh347ytxE1ZfQd3xlvqwIKj3gxIew4O0cQt/LZMkilBosQfEhXTzfv7dLok2eszulaOniIvAJprV4256rgSFWlWQ44swBBgGgKMdTZYXOtR2JTrG79WIQKDfZSAvDS4g4V4DKXpHi4hyHcwfUecd9w605RJF4CFoKoobpBZhZ7UC3BTU4SKcZF1jNnMhIT2jTHddtKYHCJBQGghBYQEOkLN8uFKpVXL2MsofshNLLOsKKOuh3K@CzILyoXwEPVD4FbyISSx1qNhVsNjH9xvLpjiwKx94IsgpWd3AyiEsfVp70x9ihCvRoZqJA4uOeL9oZLOQ89cQJ8SDv6g5OvNFJYDS03pLRP6wIjLMNA@1o/zDVwe2MWQa@R1rsHr6JD12siqWhThxWejDLpFZCbLa2ZMwmOl3jN6mF/ND36HZj07kCpbo5llLMdPgtCWW8aTS3gROxeFGokCY0702TPMAmUFOYm@aY14q4TBR3acuqxPf80aRQUcJDIGhe3javWqD1c4v4vuuP6HcMg4WCNuwPXAoRGdHeQPbJ@hTtVy/QKq0YMQh0tghOFEfB9RvuO@ZzUbkiV5CKeMCFGgNRx5QkcOVzWcb6Q0TFfF29IfmaqRtdRAJ57xMfTkF1ESffSn5Q9biXDUmBi4PgtLkVb5/m5jAL0k78Mb1D8fG9iA7uQ1OIyPdinCLRhCuG2K7bRybHqTZMvwUE4IR/dHq2t39yookTjvmKAK4i8HliNMGgDYHiImAxTYqrAbgdk1fKIywswub5VSPgJH@JRpitIBM2hWskJ6cV7vfkJcgV6W2qGGF8lUcnktBysnjzkZYFYTXdBz0KaRclU2LJckGyIHKMFI/upYZuGGho@9LsuYDxLt01XeS0eBSRA51IkSD/TJi/X8c8GyHyPDw3FZ5LhGs8nCMVxdKMrhdFKscjyambKN4tk6No2am8qgwKffiKdu9orhfDu3JXXF@DQZoVRd4Oq5JzZRiwlQjIxULezah9HrKQSBMyeBhe5@GCv0ui5kMsE3GfJfPHpyQqyCQbV2ESMsGlmmPZ/HLqKIQkLMNtKzw51jexHW@UYkJEiJMciAm8qReb7XY1gpIpBhKH2oy8vfVM1sSU1FNlEg2V32c72bBmtJEYlSjPDBFuRD0J5EPBCzEQBBMZjQUtdztIPBaJxzGwGGshyFYKdmInGzgUbbKJV3Ha/BP@BI09iVwQLzU78BHHfMQLz1eykgQiobsgzyZTUpoMvKHJPUWh7uhForzHkxBnC4lXLo5AjS5dyBzkafL1trY7dFoLoZyIC4pAUkzRPQwRlI4iFAP2nVeFGHgr/Sa/JH2h90ArtM0Rq6FOrdOxSFJiMROvUPbxPDA8uZL5w37ftsS@OXZNy2W8nMXSKi72RBBjSoMmHaIBDo@fRZdYfIREGjtCyNdoxxEF@HipNl3GyvC2NxCtbQtADjSp5oz5PbG4zazElxRNNvT5tep0e3wMCV5zvPWEd@9qUrBwy4va5u3bGYAKBAV3PX6puNsuS9KPhpZxufsFKxUK68XCcjFGsmCquqAtr8TvBA8DSoViobBaXJGkXbc/5qYjiqEirJUcAsyyF9jRvwHeNK/wNjapBj0GRcRzL33TuzJbmiSdmC2aA24OiSLIyng9O51SQfvo0Qd0KzxPCC8s9rP8VmLgMHxi/8zPBjDIcDkr4Rpt3/R61oCv5LpX/F76YF267dq2e00T0bgkzOmBiXrmAIiypLIkSrTvX@BCugttxwdq6OLSWL3pXtE5HYIMoKdaeLwRLbBKuEkVIcQz4zdOxjCB/Axbt3rITjMQwF0sEQUCBKBoraFh3omDREh8Jg7Bbbgt1xjiyQd6UDN5kH4utRVo7qZngfSNCEy1QsliuEMFnz0/PGWnRwdnb2sn@wzcxydHbw739vfYzjfs7Pk@2z06/oaOdmXPj16AdDlltVd74Pvq7ORw5/XZEXjItVNIKVOAVHv1Ddv/@vhk//SUHZ2ww5fHLw4BGoA/qb06O9w/zbLDV7svXkNn/UWWAQT26uiMvTh8eXgG0c6OspRrkEyK0rGjA/Zy/2T3ObzWdg5fHJ59QzkeHJ69wswOILcaO66dnB3uvn5RO2HHr0@Oj073GRZM2js83X1RO3y5v6dB/pAn23@z/@qMnT6vvXgxUdCjt6/2TxD5RCl39gHL2s6LfcqJyrl3eLK/e4YFily7QDxA8EWWnR7v7x6iY//rfShO7eSbrAB6uv@j1xAJAtle7WXtCyicpNxDFaiX3dcn@y8RaaDE6eud07PDs9dn@@yLo6M9ovXp/smbw9390wqTXhydEsFen@5nGd7nQlkDDKAWhIN75/XpIdHt8NUZ9Bmvj88Oj16pUMlvgTCAZQ2S7hGBj17x0gKRjk6@QahIB6qALHv7fB/8T5CmRK0aUuEUqLZ7Fo8GGQIRz@LFZK/2v3hx@MX@q919DD5CMG8PT/dVqLDDU4wAMDHftzXI9DWVGusJ8OJOYFYp4NwsVSc7PGC1vTeHiLmIDRxweii4hci2@1zQHNpyXpq55HbnAt70Kp@YCrn7EJ7do7190Pj44Xty5P8aOp2N5OJdIgw6mjAQXsUqKPVVFy2zOexc4E3xODQPk/EV7J7fyeLxlSrev3Mu3XU3HF8opwSp1MXFm9oFjHNPLy7U7ENSJtC4L4XY5X5XLFWU0Xb1Fg3zE3NLcUJtPxFn6WT5wRbxuZYn4eSDyvL5limSoXEIAg6micShTwCshZKRrEZ0h8WypCXm5FwRnUg2OVkULG@6Pvw4n6IX3jfEPEA4c7uFfB7HsIQGnizHQvwhEzp0TZy8RnYAVpuy1HzTvOwohXh2OOQXE1RqkIbiDmAY2FHUe5I3zc5E8txkekIWbXlIWQmO2wmOweHX9OKbIBkT9aJ5VDKFT@3RQw2woYxAKVR5VmQoJKxPlCc8Oe7f5nOFaiU8qoWOW3tZ@/rwLQ7mCqWVyoT/89Cfty206sOzA6G/q1O6Bj2eN3gEaGAWDr@AJNaYL6nm87E0oJWRPhlGxrOAuhjp2mpBn4pdddekbh1PIOLHMcTTQ2fsWaM49iCGvzipvdx5fXAAkhOxXdlYXV@rSOJEI2/wdZY/v8F88EBcoi5o0dcWqGkUFGslu6D3HEwdRhg7PRFrDyPiSeRBpZEnXlMc7kzmOgI/v4xPA2FxfTzBycFDzGQ8hMmT@UXcC1LArzNbpmAAJVFUFUvT00ek4eugKhEPGHwXsj2mWhvhD8IOm3/QxMMCCQYSLGb2@oMxcC4MLkjuyQeBQSeNbchsC6NocsDHfT2wQeKEQZlJVq5o40hvgrdjtQh6LVY0tleqdkoJSCxMYhEcgkdHWkIWx64ftGDuaYHP14LfwPmNOHwRg/AordrgFMh4EKbMBYcj8jln0TAE5MZ2FaroyZMwpy2GE6mqQIrP/yeP5ou3BkKFGzSwCcCB5VFI5zCEJqGfpVV2wzkVT01BOBXBseIdOHdWcQSUSnDkjHgPTuhjHFZ0YB95XYd5SEGUb4IoITkTZPqd6EHw/xvSZAb8LRhwAvSIWiSHLWdoPpCSBJXTCkavRBTrOrAYi5mpRdSMe30TgbmNV0w3LJgwwxvxhSUggaidceDxDT@yVZlBAGRynNeIt188IIEacVeHkdMzaruP@Eq/5xi9vhIceBp0FVNwG1nSubKBiRy@qHwJv8Bi2b3A8@ue0T5akhk44AIp1hyzx77MYWSKJHOw0PklmvQIWzmxJpKhGLTwiJ0KomkFjX8kLIyiXqYVhN6CKjr/MNVwOQTPbEwI/GAFJBAgZPsUL7AgG@S5jYjOLDda0tMsPxO9OB4zDiKQ@mV2RubPvt6mMTN2RcJWGY2iMUuE87glzsRsmoNr7C5sDp1stCNoTHlMZuKYiZiLDNWIQPiqGlCdOtnrEHuapkR@DbF/7Vw6eAmHyae4ghha4oTN@BZ3jb3U6bBN@2HllqPMM0jW7WT@hw7ZrRt8vRKn5mjkDrngSP@xH1EENM5r1C6hH4qopBuX6CkHPGpd56wRPCivnCh5cGYkjBnoROBZSv/t3AEB8sqEDSyTz51wEqnMO7Lq40B9QRdvu6HrG3SJeeYqFAqQAx80mBVqEKKMehMaaU63NsIvsW0BjU/LoDldX2tNfdjTnbbes@wxWZ1@cLtO3neGfh8voJdlOTkbiAetoAk64D4w2VvLabnXPtuB5oATSaevXp8eJyf@YjNfu3zmi7EvIQ@2QzlLU@DbuCfFd9sDqBqzwsbidiYvmu6heUIx00LTWmP0wI0/HjEQ5NsLNeMvXr1mX5iO6YE@eEw2l@yFZZgOiA9QpsgK0@9ySYPRDzD3U5E7O0DdhWZ2Ksy0aFInnNuTRAYCWhZZS4GmCAh74thqnJsfA6vH5gS16QJH5WoFk0pdty92W@CkKSqbfIqzPbSzEp6N/fbw7DkOxvnAnOZmoFsL5vpwLpGrTj0@WQuF8XRnMAaiSJOTN4D2fXM3GqPNFgBRmk9OGtT18O6eFk772T4UFa/WElKAehBoqqZ1hYfx0jTcQ@qI7GzFtFlEt4rYv5rlxwMHoiNRe1JUe1k8k13LstVNdmYi77JjWzdghMVOh5h8eRn0wB3XH2DUlzXGCqVisZgrLuMU7evTmkYNAb/BCa2SdPjy@OjkDAgpjiAKGCPsM5H4dCgqt8YCcuTwaFQo/XsUyEF8kJil90Q8VMGDcxLkCl@xkMsy1L2h43QvlNBPqsM0JYtT8q5HB7PibhtgoURzhFz9axS@fGmEcopBz9LRsOJwV961hHjSbklK8B5xs4GvbFwPfU@JyQ8EgDkiP0jl0cigJY4Vgjrpmb0Qe2sQ9O46jyBNnikbEozPpQJzpLNp1JKAemocTstEGwkfT2fq@VeGB7JFvwKWQxOWYMsR8AzJJjUsjd60bAvaAOBldF3scLi4CiqCpiDiJ85KVOPhWYbYIREuM06DgtbVcnthVI6VJIWb7YR/3x8bLkt1YJiNIy2/b5otOolq2OdHLWG4Bq3chp6Db8MrR2cwSakC2U16IGzwyDuQfUMb9@bjXsomr3MpKA1wVbB986yLw3oOCEp0OqBGiifiKjNG2FmG67wqVbsODIFpVSTEnI2UAKKfxUUpwArqmxiCXMQuWdzuY1N9T@6zxIR02KPfTwYgLL6qayYDAvBYduGcisCZtBoiMLGFM0CG70Pi7sQcWPIFy4t2p7gpTeFlhMKN1ZCYBxYeUc7nBlzWcfEXI2sBxfgaoUlrhFMbQ/EezSLAm4xZnI4JscID2mIxSzNg5mbCXJ4NMydgisXKQ@eKNsRhKmILXgp@2oYL8hEJERX/CzcQvbRtz3b5AlNY@o7tNvFcTJAUkBs@xtmoYuPeNAJLEDoeyjdpJs/z3AqKJFAXe5sC3YVtQfswt9lWMGOxfe7wihIBVd6WaE8Yo76LmhM58Ue0KHLKicNBUeuYOB0U0eO@ILsRrCxACh@5zKKWiZY48fgi52SSXiJJcSKJQC6ZpJlIUpKineATtYspUPTjM1myQC8hqySqAVYNK6gg9fQRH90UaIMfTdPgkdyJHYelhmAQjFg3WLhnEKM3pOgIjMSyPc8jeCUTPLL4lhdlOlK0kDxPahSY7pEYoFiJ8DEds@IookCqIAO9hMdrqAEyolxblMSJSaqwwDxAShTbw71aSjwXtcxSfZ2vGmIsHzu2eNZ1ogGu0svwt8QUkUEujiyPhMcWCFEIhKejLeowlOXVEsjBghT1zPQWE3BQgxKX32QyxrsBRUm0q0ByhzC5c0p2Ayj05@AoJ4nvr/ZBr@O@2KPERMMpKnx4TLxQ8swRDM9ojZlAUP8TzlgLT35mRCg9BPL1KOdG0GskSzE39mRXMitOrFcJqXBX5IDYIZ3mRp7f2xDpcA4B5R2PHiPdC5wkFqQLuuC0z0lGWoo1oM3krmFxCZUkW0zo8rTZGQI4WeUBctmJUkmxo2JECSe7ESnRcyaYRIm94TU47DE/KJgDUqVEKqT/vApHc8d4w54br8jjiWqfxxEhrKDe72KLMHJQ73exBY8cq/a72SI4KzokLaWf5ItETXASoFGiGDHQnFJcBgUBo3is0UQsQmjciJ8VY9rKDGxjUlXMdUpTqlJIInE0XDIPeox4xaTERu4EOwLx6mFtNKLSQh9nXJqt8MQLUfpwiLQtJ7sEXpuTBz1hoYMcqI4aKl5JEiYAic0nwcSYucdtN@nEoDQfsNAYFE9F7XSTu3sTYINepaBOK5TB6UgR8lszkc9Nn1IVDbHK0/fvhNZlAms0eHK9FsaWpRkrvtI9WGViWCVLF6uhJInnQMo9CFLuAZDyMUiiYS9Df0nOlIfnAJv3gTg/n4ZBj3cwkBIwQNK2LJzExnHwtT6@D@YCKFspsqnTuVVZmCDSk@@D8XQSBp273g1X44RnV8dZt4@m506eejaXsklemYFRiFVqGq0sokVSm8a7Il6gKtHYVrtsdq1wJJC6v6b5OREiMZoSd8NFoFTy1KIQWNT@i3Pol41Va7I9cMQT0zCgLUuf2Rw0JASfYeJbxcIEMUGWHIeKgCQh7g6dFH40Wp08XQIPlJ@bTL23JM/4hE9s0qkIReMSK8FxwRAuEk5BbxXIt1nDs3vzT83Mv@/2Qcdpz0SA4vdwHp9PSk2I9Eg1nRhaP6gvm9mfTZcrrrdNnP328Eb@ZKroJSg6bkyHRu2Y16L3vwuyKEtQA7@FJl8PeGQOko9nIokL7bqY3GLOsNc0PekhTZ2n0PDBx0jzOVeSUilWM2DILE4eohug6HhkU2SJajAygs@GfVyv8blxJzZunCMzOQNPxsXb4Sm2JmMWNEfbM3VHHEUkOsyOh@sXYdwsHo@Om7soB8sxgNC@GZv@fM/v/GiZIgQtku8ga2V23SNX0@31HItslJNAi@uayjg5puW@cxScUKuhWOVJRSXgHVwMXeKaudCXQDFXZ0@BPUR7ukshAiael6UY8E6AvptHy/OJOeyHpAyr5gGknKVuhbPcD1C3xg9Vt/4bUHKyQqWYW2gPooMt3yvUJgf5dOFtcPB1b8bRLW/ODg4SB540x8GooGd6q4VCAQ/BmbrdDhcocJXYcvPJ2HmcE8/3r7/03jTzmDR5n93M6@wQB4iKsXFpAvkElyaG0N/EjtPC@RwHd@V88HlMfgJPi5EZpxUat785I@YjkEg8s8zeYwGxfO9ZcKM0KI58yCCgBPZmkBrV0Cs5MJMD8qBHG0/UCU3SCBiNm8WuBVz4qG7fSI/EFY80z4fX8ag30TZE@blp226WvXU9u7Ug892hyQQHB/EEBR4FTQl54/HpeogsM68sO3ZFBkZB3Fzb1Gy3w@9Ywvtz@ewn7WXyzD6upCnYj52Ynf1RX5Hr72RgTChyBouZYXIDt/d0ZOiiZFpCvx8sP5AM0H5Q7J7eVwyi02Rk6APFXqrIBRgt4yWa3DoY51N2ochozKEkoqj8XBhOs/tjI1Fno6t9cC1HgaJjsITb5WjrN1UvlWRO9JC48vmo2EYaFjgMgRMegfiwFLcVPHTqt//g7DbOHODmRprjDbfExs4bi5cjmIzHlsWuBu02NC8@E78dHDUWgCNRmSuSlQKSRlSsZ347BH1GSbf9ND/ADk1tTseOkUCkXmpkWXo4aG@kAcLvVEYpaIGi@QE90Wziqxw064Mh3ZMSyTOahkMDimm5gwkuMIEkPTaq314rtVqNLfYzGVar7YAjl2O1nRrbQ4@dHbYH7zv4/qRaWl2tcMu5PfUGPHcCz1u2AzCoC8I72fbgFcLoqiUcSmEVL@ari9nK4kV1a7vi5@u1nUY@3wHX3/3@T/7un/5JviZevseXHXqpvwsjaZqWXzRuFp/cVvC9vtdILzbri/1GulNBLkNx/9rzdVuPbRPTjH@Qe3GDnfOGykCjVavVNEt/@sRd54PI6UVOvMQgSq7b/a5OyRlB2K6ma@knT8C1VU3/OK3iyR3CXw/9P4I/U1GW03oxkZaWj2unu4eH8XuCwvtH26hp4oK7LozTLMe3oFDvU8Hqea7ONI01cux9iB4adF/wiEkUWRotRjky3wkkg9IhZgEAag5yI4cGadVcvbi22silUimZm6lZhBm3TyULJG4Yxc3Ven6H7I8CCyYKI2sxTPS4Vea2dQQjAxIR41f4rlWFt8cHmcJBRxPeKc5uGN13K/NrXMex6/ViV@viGSKT966H59ZGN6/TxesBQGPibINJgNz0DsbLVCdoCciwcsU7dODT1fRe3H/DVoK1GrGH3bXHHRuvo6RtCP41tHeguyquSLad4JxBzIGnbJptXErkbYQoFtsGR6qWibtLHQPn66GjdWw8lparUMFFxKCTAYehziBOtmjjLmrFdrjxvdsGp4qXxgcXLlO9Zei4JKoTXBex6dAVnj5oWUt90Ab7PCZSFd4jw1UsA5lNC5OHR9MmjH1VpKQlMtxNCszar6ONXLERHI@vCtaTu71eD@QJZ7LQGAb0tR4O7nC6AYiDKTQ6yxUa3Zi9t533sy5kJvs/yppnV@I2viALwuwssaRJ2fHttLLKS4Unvzr6QJC57/q@JUxARHWRfQvff@sB1PO0xDMTXBO/snqpTwVNRRnbvHVyljJHwO84w8RP84DcoZCCGxIR0SwSbfq4xVkqYelK95ajMGuaA8vgm5B47guBlOvTQRvoy08kmZsRqOXc0DKoaMrhnIn9ncLGkqo8gkN0wv2@zB8a3VCp1YlmgfEOxzc4D6VfD5kkrJ3ziEgRxJATCECSKAJHmvYRFHyUYFDb7FiDRJos384sdm7yUtwGpMfG/p5sCWPUnaAsWt0Ed0aHouG9oHdg3twHcRSEgaTc4HbLs3kvKAz2F9zKKUzJi0RHUmxM80colwJ04lhDSwbyYTPOJmuIui3sRSyf8zGvk4hVWVQLd@ZAwAWKXG4s0R55AiCkxiRNcnW8OXeCGiBWJ5pBJI0LCfAxBkbmjveRJKsmyMuri3e2U0I84JcA09sZN8H/Y@abqMqmh4e4QuODWMgHoApEZtpNiOEYkd4QgpzZAq/NQAVGMWzRziBvaINOzc2/Rc8Sv2w9yjTEYyKroOiihnOkg/SDo8Dq6XhdTiQNyhulbiRT59L8VISb4GyEOMdwjVqIChrC8WlbcZCCSPOId/XQ1wa58aMQlELwehuc2SCOPAgtwYM6ExVBna/eRqKhbTnK@KjKbmcxTDBmDmR/QAmhd6ApShw4waKzfkS8uH39DNLd0pRJbThwDwf/8Do0zZURNlY7pjkOnQFoDTqonUKB0NW8cIGzTldG/wOp4VjXFlQ23xmi@ya4JYnrJWJEJ7/0OzvuSClkz@VzOVtc21RlGpeGWlrK8EFzSBkmWjB7/197V7DSMBBEz/oVaU8qKVTxImrBoxcF9eahqW3QQmtLUwWR/rszb2ZnZ5PQighevKXZ7mbn7WbmvU12wqy8VK1H8VnfSHsvxbGvnqaTCfER/VgBVdWrWdFQm33kFelPc4JVDwG4C9dedp2Hr3o0iDihWON4uRo9z0c4vFk8rEYf1xSa8PP2Vcbzntu7oxDFHy1FyZ3cuVcTIiDdDevSOCe@ZSKWqEfEh8ZrEIZ1KakJjES0AFA2AJBrmv1VaqyDwdsvawXGrRFNaVAL4S2VvItdSA6@AgKBtwOQLhrKOZqbqj8q5I@TQxSJXKjTSy4IO2fcWakhQmCWDbhOkkIvZjDDxDvA1aRWns1ogvahYHaaspCdhoX1vipU9qzHL8P522w9VcsaZgW7uFKeCRRv/EUPNZOz9nH2ueklbzi6QCHSGQcGz0t0deycHdzu45Tu0qh04KgiCirRQitjLEuFXqIfsB/LfJFKqJCRjOknp5gf/c35lrER7j8IQoQTmnPSNDccsJcxd2JEMvxZ9M3M6k4iTbgfBAp342jJPllc88aPMY8wp1yHM7HB/ZfA2yWwnGHIhhGloFr1tWXxYeKkefUa@3XzrN/D6rzXvDRTULlazMPbjSoynLR1n1WmO4h3bP@1nN2h5xJO6KAK@yE9o@kkN1pCGcNGNAenkRhEZj8KsNWTEc8k4HKWmnFMcO66JJEc61vchkgV@qf0uU69A2MyS1vcGzXRCJ650YhG0aFeas8YEP5Kc2oSnKpGtxjY9OErr6LFCBb6mjJNT@SzGEAjk22R5jYNdgJVNoE6/hlQ0q82nKTk12BKAUhR2uzvt01fcx26QdPf67Y3v@GXAFzHiHCtjRaii@eIrmP15mgAA7M/EzL8BQ)

### Explanation

The new language is the same old Haskell we used before, except with the language extension `NegativeLiterals` enabled.  The negative literals extension is pretty simple it makes it so that when Haskell is desugaring negative literals it applies `fromInteger.negate` instead of applying `negate.fromInteger`.  Usually this doesn't make a lick of difference to the way a Haskell program behaves, however [thanks to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48268851/4040600) we can use split the two versions of Haskell.

```
>data B=B Integer deriving Eq
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate(B a)=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$170:[128|B 2==((-1)::B)]
```

This prints `128` normally and `170` when `NegativeLiterals` is enabled.  I  replaced the existing code with this.

#### Grass

This program would have added `vw` to grass, which is not something we could afford.  I was able to remove the `v` by not `deriving Eq`

```
>data B=B Integer
>instance Eq B where(B a)==(B b)=a==b
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate(B a)=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$170:[128|B 2==((-1)::B)]
```

however this added another `w` making the code as read by Grass `ww`.  `ww` is a bit easier to work with than `vw` because `v` is a delimiter and thus is really hard to add to the program.  In order to make `ww` work I had to move all of the remaining Grass into the Haskell program.

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
>instance Eq B where(B a)==(B b)=a==b--WWWWWWWWWWWW
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate(B a)=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$170:[128|B 2==((-1)::B)]
```

There were only two remaining `w`s so we are all out now, if more are needed some creativity is going to be required.

#### Balancing act

The insertion of this code caused a few languages to have unbalanced parentheses.  In particular the Brain-Flak family are upset by the `>`s used to make the Haskell literate and the `s`s upset alphuck.  Fixing this one was pretty simple we just add the relevant open parens

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<ppp
>instance Eq B where(B a)==(B b)=a==b--WWWWWWWWWWWW
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate(B a)=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$170:[128|B 2==((-1)::B)]
```

#### Prelude

Prelude of course had a problem with me adding parentheses to the code.  In order to fix this I first tried to minimize the parentheses I used.  All in all I was only able to remove one pair of parentheses by changing `(...)` to `last[...]` this made the code

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<ppp
>instance Eq B where(B a)==(B b)=a==b--WWWWWWWWWWWW
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate(B a)=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$170:[128|B 2==last[(-1)::B]]
```

From here I just started adding the relevant whitespace.

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<ppp
>instance Eq B where                                    (B a  )==  (B b)=a==b--WWWWWWWWWWWW
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate   ( B a             )=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$169+1:[128|B 2==head  [(-1 )::B]]--}
```

Now since this just needs to be spacing I was able to move parts of the comments into this space to reduce the size of the code

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<p
>instance Eq B where{-ppWWWWWWWWWWWW-}                  (B a  )==  (B b)=a==b
>instance Num B where{fromInteger=B;negate   ( B a             )=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$169+1:[128|B 2==head  [(-1 )::B]]--}
```

#### Incident Incidents

I had quite the struggle with Incident in this case, but I was able to get everything in order, in the end my code came out like:

```
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W<p
>instance Eq B where{-[ppWWWWWWWWWWWWay Uce stagehere]-}(B a  )==  (B b)=a==b
>instance Num B where{ fromInteger=B;negate  ( B a             )=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$169+1:[128|B 2==head  [(-1 )::B]]--}
```

Comment: I think something similar to `data B=B Int;instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B 128` and `B x= -1;main=print x` might shorten this (and make the `Eq` instance unnecessary.)

Comment: Might also be able to replace `B` with the use of lists.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen If I were to do this again I would probably do something like `data B=B{u::Integer}`, which would give me the function `u` this would reduce the need for parens (shortening the code drastically) and would mean I don't need it to be an instance of `Eq`.  However at this point things are very fragile so I probably won't be changing the way it works unless I'm already making edits to that section of the code.

Answer (score 11):

## 181. [Ropy](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ropy), 10000 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]      )[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_      7 )(22)S    / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x18&1&          -xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              /112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@             /"78"oo@  h#115 o# dO 8=,_        x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps      # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._         #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]        #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqTqTqTTcTcTc                              #
##############################################################################                                      p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<][4O6O@]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#  
#**  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9          L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                          _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyY
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"' pp
###;{a=1}={a:null};if a then console.log 39 else console.log 180
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|******[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss          <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s       e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=96los*81''cayY
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss_ baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                       @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155" )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//      $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/pppppppx     eeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkggQQJPgACVSg@uthdVeSQrKrpAVGsRCJBZBHIRGcCJFAstu2eZHP7OJPuZufO5nZ12zOrk2nNdB/WTpLZne2ayUz39Wx/RO/HNZnmH4zcPSJfeJCsmV07gQQyMsLDw8PDw8Pj3TL87m9@k8IPO3J7k4ueO2RDyx@ytmdfWZ7Gnk3YU8P2S8VVSUKouncx6lvO0C9LKaYzZjum3YZ3NnQvLcf@aHngX2Rs4LkXntFnw64xZJZvGgPLZ@5oOBgNmduZH22Vsb2@@8HOYcy@7VwA2NDyBp41pPA1xl47PaPfahtTIaWpBAcehPts1@p96n8aMtPt9w2n7QPkOmMvXc@3EN60fN/F6BuMjfcscwrpJoAanu2@qL/6cipoi7EvgURj0LPGzGj5Q88wh7brIE8K7OTV65OjqRi6zt6c7u9P@xbZ1znXYfsj83I6aJW99nyjZ0zjX2P10dA9GE77l1j9wnIMVtS2tOJ04Dp75hnJKFScR57bHpnI6mHXAgqweDp2z/IlE8BrbCCEQkMHSzHPMtocDLCeuH0rTrXPHMtqM39gmXbHNgkRs8ZDy/EhQV9jNuTy2u71WNvqQYQIu5llvstGfsyr1TO6mqlJHddjmArrX/aYzczBgPEg1rOBpP3CJrNQaNhHCO91fTYe9Jlv9yF4aLqdjmWxj9agy6S2KzH4mIOpTIVvyxbAOFbAGGsAhY@McVFWgEsBf649YzCA3AoODO0@iLY9TPvMMnwbKw9E8S2nTTwdhNXKZYYTZxe7sqFwIeMjj3D7locFoxFe1rU8C1AaoWAr1549BF4iL@rsyDI8dupZlpqsYokkITEXUxhiRjQq0u3t9N7hfhqKlsfQjAEUpbd6@qOvJINpVbZ8XoFvVZYr0t6rXXazfIZuXqOg@AeeYqis@h3z82dnFnzHeit/4d1KgFUCrvRY3h0M80ZuAATmhkBg3kAnunJXRW3QiyXMtqfKIiZwHKoNpcEOHPYmSzkzR56HWiNiqnEJme65zgXwEzLrjRzkh8PWC1AEpguVPsusK@Aa1DIqI/eaOHzataHQfCySWKXguo8YCtoPhFhwNEjXd3sjgoOY/hAlGbgCURHjQYe9YR3D7mEUCEdUnGrP8ke9IcYZOW0sedBtVltjARmm20agvnsFyRmAlDxA8PuxWklEATAUhEtZxaAf/sWftS8uAE/dNF2vLcT1DWu7Jmlpg4gF1cdQYF3H6BFZAJfF1Hl0SODK6NltY4jJOxORBBFBqV67o16buZCgd21DHe0aV1CvoWqZQ4sLOVfsWdY3LrkusbnkQsb7RgsKlhKgtCnbOfZ0B0rJtKQUyUyuPxp2NllusMfSfv6d8qSsPFk6s4A4VVNXlvP5iwoInLZCXvCWvkty3tQTus8fGr5rt6XBZNh1nSLLmUw2q@7AcpR0Akc6m/ZaaVVDHaeoFbtqah3baSvpbZDFGiScVitm1WzY5WZlKno8SUBzjWiwulqKqcoSqByqFFf5vmE72mDC3uSEKxbm@ufIcgzWYt7ImGm/K@6RooYN5dJFAQE9pPk9yxooBU1XUU0g3Nx8Y8C8nE7hEBku281MOpXOxLNOGCCniYxiZT21XVRbvUEX2zRgiuMPoB3wUHZNA6THx@ZgCNZFlrVIrqkNAc1COvHaSnsWa4EiDeSIqiSvchg/h4pSYIiqULImW@1YRQYlAHV56M9o4557DQkSTdjIgOpwMFHjAooGIvOM1HlGeErkk8zSpQMKBbG1LLaZa9lQCbC6gU4XMh/LG4CvFjkMYOOVJKZ7@sYEsJi8UY0qDLM7UJf6oB68CTMt1DmgfCzeoGAiI6p/PthTaFkVcsVSKVnHZqrY0MvXcz8BJf0xf2dNwszXEyYDtDwd65r1DOdiZFygSedAFMM0rcFQKCrIiT8EVTTd3pBnTjSemt@Vlp9Op02NSGBYRGmgkuelJ5pCA7WLMOpyPVCmzBBmKWvbHqil3mQ6dQC4mkpcfo8gCQLeywtICCwAEDJrbJmjIWg1EODrrm12QWaROofrRd4ITScPXvHUQbPnOmHSSIxee1yUtHzohWQsRJHDEp3FA40roqolPKjw4x53Yzb8/hzEbkgiNAQxXy1vaCB79@Dsu447BykwMkSLIMkQXg5giZ2gOQkNV2B2UWUNbcywiKDMQGtAzQf56w6HA78M7YQ97I5aGkhK/tSbHAwPHRSW/NCb2EOXu1s9twVq2Yf6mQ9SyJujlj2eyhD5hWX4wZeuwADr@KwKLfe3I5A6Jd3xQWGS/w4Cx4JkUtyEgv/KAEhAGjBK6fikivdBqZxMHFORNapKGlQ6OctkrLiyCg6MFfJlx@2jFmJvyTBASw9MfNvpgLYSOp9UvjG3qQt1P9l16bT2wbUd5Sa9tLSULqdroNmXlp6AaxtdT9CVAdcTcuXIhXAauihGllwY2qAY6NdM3zYCzGO1icU2xlbpoz1QjEa5vNrMGg1dPIv4VEHVgWYD6Bw@AE9arVbRqapy7RoyqrU6ydzvoHY@MT17IJjwlXFl8HfBhVVig90fuB4asBVsZO/mSb/qQSsIRqvZVbz0WaNw1jy7OWtnzm7TWYytVoxqCzIF6Sl97cJzR9Bcqo21ck5vqmpjFRrJVjVdSK8oymauBwkZqvrFppoxOLeVtAVaWzk7SwNTBX8aZtcjfONsUVVDVgEd2DCDTaiktZtNSL@lNtVMGuKq6Sx0MarpNHDGRCb4lGmUzASDDo@/5ozZyWQkEkPXu8TvjNoHPw26Vzz6PsjvzsmLRKe0fwnalZl@D02RnMetEXjNr3DPNj1Ci6vMDshidaC5hRxAa9sOe0aO6@ScEdnPZNy68YSoM4gQ5IdtD@pVOwGDiDv2GDoIUO8ngSGE7TfaQjvQ3XR7lvaWTBOZQcVhWN21udbQEW9WNNOPZADsHnAOeoYJFTuJ7kxmZ4AQ5Dyfnx@iVmYQT5tK1Ku5L4/QsJiGg/xr22S1j2y/i@wFywq7El4HuIomO9gGFnHtgJnQ5l8Ap62xPeQ2PMjRCUZ5bviKilZjnVtdaOyhxYBEBSMA1Jy7JvR3LLAcMJR3Htmec2V7roNM1vYANQh8BctgCvk89oIY1esHxd3F/J2HHDg2463HeBvHOs1c0zdZ3nF77oXLVgAARVPTuGAfOCaQADbfELqXzLc/EoPqFy50fJIyaGFz76ONqK@vhta3gZB5gtc@gK5h8zMdASzI88nBT/aghdBLhQLQH7wV6BNmMoZlOo/oabIIQAzP9VBusCR/Yg26Ey8hTr4repEgT67FKybv1xvQoAJVooZ/pKjxSs59oJ4HQe3ANS/ve2Qh4VBGvJeRyD0Yg1BPRXZ4tYEcpqa80TdgRQLpTIFH5bsPuvO0O7Iky@y6TD4DC6NYY/m2dZVHhSODouuCqZyDpCyPjLEwmhgulIbuCKy6ttWz@/bwgAa7eg6aLlGzHITuQAWLEBzZ1lAS/Y1IveKAVKRrnQsOvzfGBsmXLHqyV4e7e@dH9dPnVTk/8r18z26BBLet8z4Ynj3Ll9n0J8WOLUAm4n@87B277rDKi@uyx@79pDBOEP3F7vmLg2fH9eNvOBGExrf7o56BpJSXpwAw@gkFB7UqNgrY8dx@aJH7oiCWV5H1VmJ8F7unInQNQ0didDfmv47@fRyx1UzpwjRZzuWvoacA3EBAHMWlNuwik0FIGtUNPQXkJqHEkV3NawWeW@gZjunGOj1xdPPCF0cSmG/0wi0i952RP4jl7EbXyf9q2Olgqx16F8n7Moei3ou8V8mbjwknkgrYMhM0FzjEt0b4@FjyXHwzQXOBQ3wljg/HoOejmwqZBxoiWydkOGY9F9dUwBxALpanoAhfuNB8vbB9mneIy6kUmllnkhzYigmjSI5CitGYDctdzR9skuOIqAaBkF@62EWJXOcFTS8hlhBF/7I3G7MDLT39JEBniJoN4TW33@rQzxyAshjHACWFw/LIla9wLBaHWlywu6xrAqMeGSEDbtmOkT@mB/bN5tGT7GUmiGlZnRGYJHkwmdF9D1hua5MgO62WvQgU@IKkB885YN6oNY9t0EPszgxEsATjhyNv2LPa4vlffq8NBTBbPF1jQmZY6DgHvpFsdBaWloiKL/Qzv2QJ5sOoZxvEBnLdh9I0cOzX6IWO@aixPWG5XNfw@mjtiMIF4cQfUEF3yBmn3LN6o7YVPOcnQixODnfw2I7dpxzBE8116pwsiD41WMPjk8Hbc402YeFmqW1Fpc3LxRpzAy1m94CWfwCdwZgKiyYxht3RcMR/cd7ivnK1B/idz5VyUsgKJaOlW3nXN1q2dYcceMblqO3mBpcXlGkkbX2RtPNKhEMAuU7PuOTOc3TOZwDPomdfXFhe8FwEdt0FS4tMxPw1Pe4QlaCdY2S5GHfh9Hr8dxFIMEscOhbzye7Rz@cIJImICbUGWYtTk7kYm@wpxvaM1gRN5e7nSxYmSAYEKJ6qmckUVrEJC0eio0nQwWBxfGz3KP7W1vzYfFKUs2SeAZnnk6E5PkxAeRbTo/fUemi57L7RyxXbMedCJR4MQUWuOaDUb8qZPcMHYRqK4rCuoPjo5y4Bx8bIRLGKXHeId0ROMCGxaGw7ijOwTbdn@wNe48TLIm06PSoYocHZafqJouLbLH/b0D3Chj4XuuYrBNcc4vjyAnl7gILjQ7s4eB4TIM1dxDvTvcbvQhOj615Z/Hd@o/dxLlUPUFW5HkmGbc6J3jbvE1ecoaSf@Vy8nEvV0OzN9S@zl67rdS3HZ0WtEAxm4fSQ0evxsebTg8PFMu3bPdeHjhL@3sUL6BD5Pv@dL81xttmGk6MRv7h7fjRB1IBpYoRjQWEavQu3t755kTfgZ2GJj7wOtgDi@VDNF2ouXb9fcwUGkuvo4rlQ5V/mvcv7hIGGBT2cPog572hv56kvMey8OIPQjcA5wfmZ2y9sUkwtz3utiwrAM7vXxiR4/hatyiLuBq3KYELmNdh/GGFrExxDj5vcv01qa3en1n6YTppBu3FfJmKFe9mzQEPT70yRsmJB/8wYeqHwcA3V6Y2skTVXYxy2Pli4musOXfFwogoiG8tifCcPzMPRnRDqo@g8PohqbL/x7U4FY/RsqOT3Wjlz9d0AbPIB9rePwHGEjtmIF85okCjcGO@OR87x3ZzrDoKa7bYTRGLI52qkzfttqYTZ7lv0XWTi7/Vd6CK7fbAZnAeUv0BKQ2L8N4GYfCLMH2wca/TuxFtm4Twj2LVgf0Cp2pd@DgcsH6Z4iov69gS8tQW9N8caTvB3EbfnKdKW6/Y@p3RAn7ZtNMvA2MQVf/eV0oytI6acWTSK4eOISKuzaPyCtzWiowncw071woI@giwNqXF4SCnPjHne0WrFRkDv629Ci02DRL5nBu5F9B5j5da1TW3jToK5Oeq2rJ7BH@P1tbvwbWmrDzGJBoGdSyPmOMrOx9WjiYnUlAoaTIBZdhv6Kl2rb9HrHUa@0f4w8oPHQqCxi985wVqeRokXxBvYUOcd/E2M4cesoqHrQO9qaHgXFnZPeji5JHwX6dlg8Hkucw/6xoW1f69wRaMUuB6Jd@oi5/zxijJfImBCtHs0Ce/5uc6lNfGD53z7eGJCeY76d2KbV89NHAy9t2Jr@blj7veYfU7X7Tpdq@tR5QjfFlUPkMghX8p9VyaA/q7hX@ICLNJJUbeu68e523N7vYdwF3Ui15CuO3@cdg@XTrch6mfhnRgtCBCPe4f0oOkmJlEbvqjudK0RtFC@O3QHVo7eFoH2cPCH/84fej44TPvsrW15bT57jCOBxtBu9Sx2bQMJH/z4lOX8gaVWzzVwjd8dRjxwJng@ZKjKdL17x0EuDHc4GNDjfNAb@fRDQ765zvyxzDLbJ0ofIgz2kE/cc5G1LtyW2bXvI6llGUPHvswHYzr8db6YJ5Ux5dxmuV301no28MqbaCgE1Xj4CT4O5ld8@4XYiXGnQbIz8rzJ/cohOSUbDr/ySQN0LBqAEbNnc4Kp6cfVKcEqjDtmLsRk20KJImMaDeecVQDrRF84HJRYiCNY0FtdHd7DJdM1L@@1JxYOZIp5WhrSs2NzzeA/PYpxNxnPhX6D3qHyfHThq/cLbrcNdhX@zBWS@gUXEJxY8nvudWzgGaq@4YjH3LjFF/enTrMjpTsnSspMf3FePzy4H5nZswc@/2W5TnGuqTA7xzoLNZnf9xVF1bY6/Pc@@67vergeGQyJnOlZvonj4KiDuW7kisdxL0AX53osAg5g55I/O6U7z0JJtnO5H7@yLgxcn/TCxqVKPX@26QPM07O7D0H8o5Hh2z8auUNrLs7pWd6HoHxpXNjm80QJBAgD7orFLPyRUJboNVsQ113bp2WhgWORHQGCdrc6nB5wD7co3T04ErORxBo9ljtgwVq@0IFD/hhuzE0rbr67gztVMp87P6atNOGiaz8r1gqBn@2JHR@@FmyrStG6KlqCHSzJZSlcGD5C3TR0PY0RnKIYmYyqSjwSDvNeOAAWQNHGFlz0zvfM@Kxn@0OCtTus0WDLN@NyoazfsiqTyzJrNjlW/NAS7L3xgHalHPPojWWjWV1O53Lp5fSZU2aFdAhu9XxrPriRgO3Y9OD0RixgjsFXz6E7yHGFL@r3u7RhBtrzNtgFr6E7SW2D6/Gl6XzfwynOL//nv2yLfUTQefBZ3wbtAgzBTXRu3@q61094uiL1@mBg4D4kxAHC2OOr4nM7deZfowHBtw@51@z1/umm2JQgduzByxG2dDEqeOFiTxaXFA554XFqwuVhIuEwVpAp0@2N@g6YbO1h19fYiU2rBUdetOwHXAjmDD20W9tZdsDaFs7i0SJQ6qr1XPeSVnMjJf/5L/lWDFoKKpboBcnTFqxYirjiU6f9D6bpjoDqAMlHy3MFiIJMBsUxwoEQEG6L@6u4QJL2iIBE5oIdEpQM3yaxUz9huT2Wxs2IuPC6YneU5frxl28ahWb1O9bPW//l9/LqjWCc/EVua92XsywAqdyiYMWDSxAchaaZvDyWeYLhOllb2AfXvDyARQYXMlwqG8iY6w5EraFdbrSpK5RGsbNWQTeVc7BVok8b5EhgrWvaKkHr0xxUqLjzzPGhgsGrSqh5rasuKyPeV8@dDFkJEsTtJga4@JY6WjmKy/4xyvKYfWJdFLKciasZ4Y0zsoc7TfrVZ8GyjtX44pv8rtUa0YzzVVErrlYpO8vn1e0auTyr7eKOr8a7s3GxkDsbb@w1837A1LOz8ReF4o@B6y50I5Yf57Hm7b3avVnWaoVPn3xjwmT5Nl3hq4lATSzfHB0c7Z2c1k9fn0Ap3AbqZ9/1@kaka1CKaH1i1@3RXjrgi2db/mfon/ANwBWFLRtsG3cEq6oUX3pHoILXck5e5s6YakrEvif6vPi@FQufBRA6rWOzQKKiJdvQHmBhgtQh@5ALowFuDWQCidjeROJmo7LHmhRyCBdvzVGqxDOZVYFrOeDaA3nGFuf6Cfd7COvuxXI3/57MBUHWhek1wnCexbksuP0HyfcAWszfPd8cy935Jpg78g2goW8QZ79@8OL18V4yGggbPUn9VrdKYvEp19JY5Xh/P9jPRev0RUQc8KjKTKYI/FW0aiPc6dOyhtcWZEtoSbPPI5OEEv2yFAkmcKaKm@ebFc4LRSEK0BipYLam1sZ27HGMxKCxjqG74VkMtcG@HKIOCNdkgTlFW9s1/ATZQKyCXUEdPCJtLhR32o/bQdmgxmHWsLEe@bzOLWizwubHZ/Afa54CV7HJxky0a3qT5VgRvj0LehDdEFat8MaKLXNGyMucdjmkFzdWA03tDwb1OGhlkFj@C811zxjgLk4B/Qqs/DL7duTSXoNAmYSGxjVasgY/QYCK1jQwN7SHwRnijsygASN8B/snVTTTuI1Gij4ucyMHWywAiu3o3xtDRwKErUNKn@8N5ix3xTbUoM2kgShfbDsLzQWfXdk@DVRhIXTQ2OmBpsTciIxDYfBdJqze88E4aUM7DqbKENtcsFI0Wt7K17jmHCanQCa10HbMMllCWL86uy0R2tRrE9rX9zzyMsERZl@as3/6zMr/8C/@jO@ZPhuC@w@Fe1x4Bm9/LN464P7nQYiuw9u/DN@K8PYz/vYujxyd3SjKcxMyERn45uCI@TSWhizqG@NY7rHiYlHazgiKtQ@8viLWITjPVsSZCI/SeAOch@ICtqP5gBYDpWd5TQW3@ZXzebSucQJEo4WY1pgPpNGuv29HuNsdjJz8eml9Tc8DkbmrACFtvbnAlX8coaqWQdVIV/ag@r5lsu3tbSb7ptGzqusVzvL8svFuVX4fEroMsBI3xBsM4kCUKAaE1UQ0ZdnI6CpGxfYhradRVbRdXoJgbSnkABAVvZ1g7wKYc65gFYiHY42HZJFMgg4G6EGHVsNb/MyDAFEOEHHcuCd7WsqjtXy49Dkm91q8GOS3CHaCYGV5npA13rGz4ZnTFHvzGQjML@eInAPuP5qzYT@UnvrsTnFlep835oY9PXFcXPO5D9QypZgvrub1dTVWp2SBCujFGvQJUEKdgTpoWvYHd@DXd/YOvjo8OpnZ8UyQ6WmwNEvXtjNnOS3baIaO9JTUB0x9tp8/eflsP2BlnKpoKhQhovnQaTLnpTZN6YLU3/JFlLNpU8BMQnrhoYhp4iG3T0sGZrFHofkY4A5fvDWTqqLe3Daa27UzJzWT/Kd5p0CktBUULnCd@XQGRJrN0TkHwdLQUzxJyNeCPQRFOTrjJNw3wN8j78V7lsNziaKNy8EiVIm2FIU7iiRtwfJUyLuW50nRrl1OWEAv6JqAVB1JjRI0pZnp7Dg1TORl9gglsYEiZNIhH6OhwxgMB7rlnm1yaJ8UNB/JoRMEoA9/EGuNzS4tYaGe54R68qAqwkHktk3jcYYX7GUJQ06svp07DehBxRFtRBY7cLuQt57dqhjVxpiFOzDu2o@r@YOePVRwc/BYwxESyI2iYgb0bdxdO1a3t5piIzML9htnaMvy0Qj4deQOWDQ6tWsFrmMwUdjuCJCb2L/5atQHuA49ji1sJSwwWnIQGfiYDoho4CZdkQet3y5B6lrXGrftC2hpFDULKukLXY82Oxu4W9dJgx7mrPoS1/jFGfNZG7RjHDMahmY7bWus4F64chO5A/7p67dXaVWekQHaJS72BLent4sHysIYilobbbWeUghbW6EiSNadrS2t60u4QwaMYUjxZOi9ACe0oUqnbwyYMqL99j7TGL0qZ4qT9YeeynI1bM@umcMyGepUw4MCwFZG0A65bNrYqODxNEq@CuWMvr7TxsdHe8AauqY1wU2JqGwZB9R2wNzAoShVgr4RRCkTWmiA4a@MFIHR2UaK@HOZkpVoyytAzQ2minzRpQoIvKBcs9rjaH9hrAZyrm5tlUVpJNXhFgOx2J6jMQDtHDUX2KbAX7HHAbiGSgygdjyrbYNCefq15ThQXxWQmT7UTmaMQMg8NRsc4ZaNjt2hFFKcxOdi0wQQmjyOZy9903PBnlnOV2hspnIL7f77M2z4O6Lpn@T/27yWr9woy73qJA/GmFpTlrtVPbO6ksksOyvKsoPmyOPHOKRzuwzWzrkGHaMxAOWWe2oF5Bmso@qyU1k2tpXldrW4QjHgFbpmNxDhOz@v3Swbt/nlx2BNZMHH47VTWfZpp3xB0/RboA9ryHI@CzJzg1u@6WA2TH7ZzmSQBm35HAn4Ln92kqF25ewkT6NHFWHk5i/6gRpJ2iphScwcKMcZKLzLoUYvoUYXC17OA@DoMJ7VeWF3Wtdf4/JARjOZlu/H5SsZ8nDFIhQaKiehZBR@VAEwcKwAE/E1a6gqKJPf/CalrzMmP1lfVdzMk1KhkkmXdOgeQr8u9RQM1fyK7Mk3Z7u5K2bl0o2OUdK@bR5dHh39WD1T2BZLp3YOZX1Nfse2iuxhnw1WXPBhv8snlVrJS6n8iv54I59///49mOTwadS0GqgP@qiNXLrZUDbAWdvYWMmub65kn6bPA6pUpVhUT6hLxM5s2x747TZ83S6doqik@OfJE0oLup3wz7ifSF84ghcEEb6pz4UzSil2tmEYK5m14lOnAtRt4WeV6eDE30346qxUYnv4@dv/429/8bc/p79f0PevDXbJPsLnssPwn9wf2zG3ge5W5yOeJAC2d5X0wiCdLq2mT96lpVTNTH1M6bqemtDfObr1sb75WH8c8Tw3nvokiySv68WzKJ8xNmCWQ2/GfVjcL@RHyG0muJT6XDg8f3J96SkDebCgCcJPufw0Sai8sSm7Lnh2IZ8l5qZY@5BtVrPnAcQ4h59xkAVBAYtyFYVEbyzulWJBNBbBfC6clAoOBss1jE6TDev4x05b@Hc8xL83l28uc28uj038e3aJfy9b@Hd0gn8DH/@CwbBUKsqQkOnwLZTyab@A6@ELCyoD@xw4KfVdtcrLg4lymfeZDdK088B1HhvYY0/gswR/9A@f8BV/l8hHeBPI7Gfpd1A/UqqRalR/t0@zGeZGSm1vb6d@1KU/D/@eO/jX@hb/XnzEv29P8e/UxL97dKOU@gf9PIwlA4mlcs1M7va2ob0bZyoV8Q/mRiV8ww93QbE2b3O57Xe1TKZBxduoiXLezjVrvNDpVzt/t91srB2uHz4F9Jntxva2dl6rjWu55rtaA8viBn9M/xYf@F1Zwd@iLOdXzshZHW8f8zR2g0RQwTL8Cz8veNKNoxf1nb3TbHE7x1LF/fpOtnjy@llKx9dS9E7Bq/h@vFffPXwNEY5e7NVP9r48eLP3@gj8/eZ57enTjAaa5ClkpNZsSKnxF5lapjocDs9/cr6ioeG5xe3PrQQp05/zOS7xLqV2a@PX@dw2UP/ifAtze0xp5oBJzU@MIz9rnDUm30y@kVLvt98rmSeZJ4Ve4aqgX@qXL93D6P/wcAwB9rjwwfUK3UJXb0M7wArW68KkMBkX@u6h3ganBX@FPjjtQmdcuCg4BUfXJ@MEqsX//UN3@PLQBWwuxByOC0NEXOjA8@Lw8CXg60DaH@DPLhQKYyByXLiC/0JPp8@78wK273jCCrwVCmdnUoPJ7y0wAzQ9rRXS2no6bTdL64Nvz25ui@vfNqjrVNpqNvA0nabMsunzs0a6WUnl/bOzPDeb5OKaXKHjdm5vz89366f18/M81qTx9nLmaSb3FD7VWmZbPJ6k2rXKk7NyDmU0kNZUfvvJWW01h@71DJRBEfy285nP/EQo4VlbOpPSyvXbt2/x@/b66pq7yMH9zt6GofjzNg9e3IVe8EHQ/Lz4Scd4VvIUpVFq3tyC@XiWrqSFgakwOvlK1s/GxQ4rytiJV7ZUsOH1VewprpeYWqutl8BjfVPNKQXs5PMoZ/JgMDiTNRrW1GjbSbVa9zxjgkMZyhogUbZK1eqZbHjnZ3Kj2MS4pdzWOnO93NaqKqvqO317G9LAJIoqeMvpsex6aXZzG/9Tbm63Ffqo@Keq6KmC3NCzpioAoJbgbXyjsG1lW0E/8MJ4N7c1dBLcDbgaitpUb2@5n3JTuVXUbY62pgLnGBjw/0j/YJj8/@f/5WvmQx/gNoU9U4etlVSlNbHUtXVlM7Ml/qpLwFlFXk2vYpcjbaQbjacrqysba40nzRW2gl@2omyf1ZrjBR81nYIaHVTBqp7C8kW9plWOZb0oQ69ugPWycmNU9dvqjVHGDvtthc7XpIk7U5zm1XMv2OoWn@SM@@mbBWwoIBUZPuiS0gyEoLYdin1YAcZqDWWGkRQwtcnU2xuoChQG/V1FTNGdnY0LBZVVWtXlm5RxW8EsyOxWFpBBZSLUSrpCS2TkG3nZ8Bp6U76Vl29atzgosKKr1B8srVUqK2vcvawo@tZ6catY3Fhf39Q3NsHQXi8U8kzXN4trm6ulrbW19c3SOqhCVa1Qgiv6isBTADzCuVmpWL5hVlDHVVJAh6KkVQbFlDqTqi3rApIHLg/i1T9TKpWW8kV4jL9Y3yuO2dKnFfo0VqA8N4ubmZVM82ljZWsLi7dJQZ@WpApO2/FVLXJO5lqDbW5Ryinfj/Bv16RGf9xp0pks1VxDXy81c2gvfhh3VoAUfWM1tRLAW8tHpBJXdlfgV4f/vSWfWvwBLbrZKLA2Tld6zO10lsCza/ishTPLvtXrBWfKXbter31tt60lybfg0z8yrJFlXY9G11b42bF948MHY0CfceeHX/70h1/@9z/86mc//OqnP/zqF7/@/hc/he9fwvdn/Pmzf79Vwt9ff/8v/5cf/vxX4PnX8P1P8P2Pv/7@3/we/9L738D3/4r5/Y34xuD4VwJcf/zr73/@F7/@/p//KXz/rfj@6fT3h3/9H/j//y3@0PmrH/713@CPePnpz4BLf/9Xv8T/n//V3/@nX@L///o///1f/au//@N/R44/447/59/@e/77d7//07/7p3/yd7///YLfn975@/0D/L//R/B5OJ0PwfOQfH2uz/e/FT2/CzeiVEAGQNL@6Id/8wcgq/@av/0zeIP/MOgPw5dECH/5w@gFMPxPcyL90a@//5O/CN/@IAmYCAMkfwhhf54I@8Mffvl7P/zFf/fDL//sh1/@MWqj3NpWtp7N6ff2eHKlB8Ah4PpD4ACQgyyxJalIT/wRnmyJXOMVqbSKndkc/2S456dltEvZ2SepBO@ZT3k8DZDlP4nQM9wMrEPo6hqFFsC@LmBoCV@D0BgpOAT15GnC/ueErHx6ygAYIseACfAJJ1T4Zz4lVDrGpPClkHD4RokthfETPeTt9@@rNQR4CsHQUFJbuY2/@AI@z6qMUccWHrVNVpWybLOKp38hYBXeKRyd9A648GqOqrTLnuGQAHrvAoewzR2P2Vh6j2M4GQKvcVBWkyD8O/B4xtEQNkT1nQReGe6zC8/vBPxYInz4L4xbdOM3CICfDON@8JpBJJmATSwjcQgmxrrGMxYyDWcgHMYb4z@LEAk8GQkYkcnGO29hEpnISwpfMzOphPRMhWWiMEZpZpKoMmwG4V2BCW9pOiKbi0VQsDB0KptB6JwUg9DUbJQwKM6gTCbJMIyZzFRGyuCa6xWR6EpmBYfi2crnfgRNlMBcdtzxifN7Jcp5HG9EfYSV6OURMgQbpU0YFW5f0YQe09fXQsSqpNCZsUylURFrAAad9NK/eOaOlUJWlrP6@vyRBhXHUAD2G7dcrn6nr21I8KT3ER5fKw5SBdnGK020bfgAHVLtJofObXSCubYu1WpispLpUu1k7xQinB4yvVjQWKPQvFnbKK6V1krF1fX10kZRX1vfWlsvba4W9MJ6oVQs6mDLbm1ubdxKtR@zscaOjn6UA/c4l8sXKYmqXtqoTKoQkbykGlmO3MKc3OR8sC6RrDOyZ29wTREOC93ksGI@gg@THknsEXjBBzDj1AoTU9oHhxUx8YkLs0Ojnc@CynppSyYunVlOmyOWBvGPdIrn278CTMAgh73AJYxDl526fKncM8tcALHT5TfU7Hiu7/8OMM8M55IH7dp4rpo5DIOeG3hqit@3h90FEK8HfdxDYnn/aBj2@i0gEIezOcAz@PF6rjsPYIO9PlqQy5fhFimcMKU9UgB@fPDl89PY83SvvvNcWmfPDl/tTj1KAqjEXuztn4avGzw0iFoKUXyz9@LF9Kt4YDdniZU2sllN0@AHn1n60FNbfheA6NpiU0NeLxQ3ZD17PrGgA3OTy91e2C1LX4fO7pqcgi4Wnm58ws9vHjptNu6QzG@t91x/ZVNPp01j8o30EtePbel8n4Ht49p7wHbt0J6JFt4uMRos9oQHeqHTsy@6oFSu3RAAKtU5axkGfj/3A0is@Gd4t8eQp0F@MyG9WXDpOXT8@njOL25DHkrX4aDY22AELBwJ47X0LY4QEIeCuXh/aHh4EdopKja6goTh3s8WntpNW6rQWKDdj3TGtgVqbkuScP7R7rCCpKHqKRa3NkubW6vFzezm1uZaCTqypaxezEJvfWOrkNUL@qYOffQtPbu5trW6BkoOQktbG1IKtIndyedBv@uyTE/bMfFcxm084NLVujUp1bY6KP1srLRVlmqHHqNNJq9unhUYRJQlXOK6Mq7KxTVcf76qM12WZIOZLLW/v1PY35flZ/iC46Y7BVlu40tps1DYeCbLFoXsgCIuQqQuvu2t4wCrLNv4slPf30cMH/CluIk4ZPmSh/CXXvCyAWAOvqyuIgImy9@G6AqA3OUUbVKsIX8pFJ7tyPKIk7cJfwBX529rROwevmAARtrnITsQJstfBpHAyJblYw4nknoe5Ldel@UD/lKvI4qvKPMlnqmv8aVOH4jkwRvUA1m@AMeFZ1mOLLfAibVBlk1wmRMD/PrgwjMenKEhyxOeD8yJLI8J2jAvZfk88Id0gJ7nz43usG1d8M/E408Tgg4gyB6P9vZbX37ZurhoeZP63pfHFPTVV8@ND5OR17poiYitc/i4GAuCLvuT6Y@FQefnRm9@0NcQ5EwFnU/OLaLw3PgWKBOfC0yof/4VBn0FQfPG6wRC@PQBuIWfZ314PjNaPCj4UBA9x62WXEGRxarTUUhwjSw9WmSK3DBcfOQrxhNSgmXUgG4H7JfRpporPRltyusbcnkFnvITeRWcUDVYIV1gTE6fybLa2Go@kTdKcjn95Eku/Vh/wuSNLbksb2xAG65WblGBKupNRxlnx9UCeOTz21ihsQrCE8wKYROcWuOh9tzCVS9mLvc28dnefgtwuPESd829GvWhD3JNOgSXzgfLnM@rz0BhFCoO7r618HV5nBpLtbYxNKDP9OxmVC4L2NvKRbWBCD7hz3ZOflt7KzdZPN3SRgGoeu2YxY3t7cb1pybYRlW9MkkZVb24WRnjc2MtbhUt9wx/uKxvFMuN0XIjpzeXlgqfLrbln9QI9S1kNjk4urFZAb@AFVzHhVoKYuDuB/jmchKGD6qibGSm4KUJOBNIa2@UdHqjmE6r6QrEXZKB64LpNFmIhRuUjQzaEcpmqwjRPWs4gsa@ULmdSdm7LJOmxp1pmEKZyetgkoE3bhyZ/3kKXf1seaVV2q79k5nPf/NP5n3m@@JH4lbmui6lbqU2nia5tiWlbqTbm9vtWpDi12wyMTJBd5o9ZuwisywtpzHz6dVk/7FerV8c14MR4vqOlMqtumtuanl5WUptn9bkVflQOw/nj2p5mqE8wylMnOHTzs63lzK/1eRSTqs95ZPONbDXWV7yLNwm18Y7Avkcz2YJC@OC@anMb/mBRKQq4JQqOMgup1BXmD13hKsvts94hra/S9EcEDu66YwcWo5afok2uGKUucXTaEKF/e6V3bvZXM3VaBWVAlJ2e0uSYR7S@ggp5bjCCYyEPtEQqq0CJntJpm6NxQYnW@823m2@e/n68PXhPntaKG@WNznfz7igZPW0noZyfArtsn28J6UGn9yS/p3zVSVVHqRX19KribI7q4pdxArKv9LA7TeN1WazAfKGJMN7tVp8opc2M2tlfYOpqRpuaCxuIMfRBToht5pqpjiStQ0V3DROX9RTtbzw1jd0NeXn@BtEKaV8KbX58j2O6ATX2dlFcuXznLDl2@1b@K/dNqBTdkt9s1v65z@3tzwc/gk8fOOP6BMDjMNE4b@d5GnnqeZ3uW3@v40/O4c8r/J6SVZT76s1kId35@/OU1Jqi8nFEva6MnnRyeIVCE2/FYf@LH8F/95FHitgrq6Eb/C6vcJKNR1ireTz@TP1R0Uw1ra21jfXU9JvgGt3rEGH0HBRZseC7g/o@DmrMuue/dLAFatOuDITHC9HH/H@kafBxYWBXcfQsMNlx2jZxf2EsRfzovs@k34TP48bx9BXktBl0323rENiiIp8SHud2AqeZoO721XpRnoEuEbmkPacwU9Fkh7hRkN8VQK4LHvsD1Ucoiuo0qNHQhP7Q80fniNyjCQ8c3pFupWQPUa77TO6AQhndPmWeAN3TbkDfu5bb8J4JJ8uaeFGKu1mx3RjBK@wDqcCcrPCKEWiHDPHk3/EwVqjDpKyf/BiD@JAb71D6yNFbNlr4fValL2ljsrCBgV4gJfEVAWnCBwBAR14chtE7eO@e5OqNMswHcM7tM4SoLJMzxIlWdYRERv42oToiL4Dys0HxDx1heeArZyLZEUeBD2UCWAh5o7aRbq@xbsws6L08Oz0RlNlN8FeRQVD2TYrqrH9moQLCoNfiUsRzX5b3PVTjdhM2PRmFoq2wjdlKiGc8IkYdSutDLP9Ci@qQUX6WjHBVHI9pfJd//Fj892g0W9W1H51iM9Mpg9t9aVic5CVYbVfBfEYNOxmZdjIZOxmta9@reA73siFDbsw@HxV5A1y7lSBFly36qvZjw0n953TzO43nAyQPMqu/KT6MWtUC2iqZe2qnu1lvwWbh@cD0hxWP2acirENX1xrnNgvC@ZJxqgkvDDKpdKrfmwYTbT9ehAxk9mHzACdfqOXyTRVSLwHgbMRK73Hj41Mrzau9HI5FaHerT7ZbwzB0cxU8b2sGNvjJx8bI4hfVuBZhWR6KhAP8QSvb0Pagb4K8JiXaUQ6p5FM0zGQ169WV37yZOUnK9WlpY@Nca7fzHL2lwuRNCDxYyS@EtuRrKz8RGVTLKEZa0X@wi5/oa3gtlI7kwEmZwexmJzClZ9AyCCTCai@RX15Gu87o4SJLYx8wyjdykDbUqivTL1mfh0Qqou6b9q2AOcHSwxsPCYBTzTK0j1aBkFgmLg5GAPPxk@eSEHSYtccpIzKBXrpBg5d0P2RuAmZjtxg/PCm@/TrPDUc6Nywk013OkF3fnU9Vl1JNVGF8z2zgSCoBm4KtxWusfheSVA2pD0AhrQHwuVQiyCThJ4QkFURCKUVFBDEQj3R4QeP0dlLqJ/QyA5rPqgQTgZU5jlk2NkPVdJNIE82uJi9TemBA6qK9AgygTRgHuwmq4EiY48fM/G6XWV6cQPbAgRDuA8ZHYFmKIXEH0Ap4EAqP4CMoj6kRIC2RxiCazQSCa39bgmJQyYUiJD5kOVnTWh01oQycnx@NgvyTeVkYFk8evQhU10TBME/9VEgPoTd/iYlmvsy2zl8efT6dO/4Zf0EfqF3uhm/Ki@4xXbmDssB3k3Zsh3az2oax7r1zVcmYwr2zvCKBbykus2@ev2CFYuvdrN48DGwPsVH3aFBLYeYLJ8uoPE117vIX9uXdn4vcTIp3idMW2f9Ml0fK9YQW3TcA91LHZ4YEx0Y4@O4ITTm4rTWxH1jfcv3xdWcueCaczoqj87O6eMRMFALxVWetCspcQgArs3I0uYwz76w6e7qLkeQiE93cg15dKofEl7BSb1kkGhpa7NQKLNCFh164CgGjtXAsRY4SoFjPXBsBI7NwLElHHqAWeeYoSe9uroeOTci52bk3Aqda4XIGWFYK0bO1ci5FjlLkTNKbS1MbX2T8LJUwE2qupaHYfraZhBGAxBD8iwBGn3acw0ILc5AQvS1GU9IbzPpubFVEAkd5A8RqFhcj95B@wSwVYVTleV0ZHnK/E14Qlsl8d4eCeye54FW2hvjncMgdGqZ4VkPkoRnqpk9ywBjwBqClVLdB/m31DK1QUNvUo4OukAMVT18h@h4YxvE0enabC4@c4KL84I5tuJcbPyILRYyJnbkhyCSU1lOtLQc41rCL451CRUscnQBRJFDYBkkTwgJ0jz1RnOTXL07yQTCuUnOEMXxlubFQt4ohLwaRKX2n7BVg/S4nWJRaYMZgDGh0EkGpgoUjwqr3uhl@dff/@n/xn79/c9/xX7481/9v//xf0T3f8Cf/x2PwiiGAD/7OaNFJvDzrxgtKaHlLVEkgl8tyz/86S/h9X/4d@yHn/6cB/3JX8jZtRARhKBXFPMX/wx//gB//k85WwoBf/FHHBCjyNlbKWFaKQD1s79mDFJDLCGyP/1LxuQMGBiKkLwGr@PN2LFAHEHIhga5mtPh/BevmgUeF9SMDHjFmx69ZbAA1Bhyz7DxrLSw7oE5wwc5UUubhtnFEzaEl@uj/WOiCeP62gXI23UbjB4xLJGG3P8@K7N0BmFwhAVPRqtyHS7yL/ItR6EIm5HzQB3etihQ0UW8ISXQvZVAvqknMPE17LZQj1TnMiL4@8qCZiJoQORAsuhiUUmkFcTGYRlxRzvdNBt0dVFosRniJ4vRBauSOAJCjyWYUDdTxQapTPtAlzE6GygelTys/gDPtqlG/EbG4gtxITuNLio5UW32DvenKgx@WmBiXsY1UphQlcnyPbDIaQGvosW1moTn9AqARqG82kycMjQPWP7xj38sSzG/AsqQ11YIQyxTXGWEQXoyqBgLKsaC7I7ASbqmVCxO0UANB@rF5FlbPFpMRSWjRcKFNScoByQD@oJ8XDTb6Y38bnUWNWnkpLKbRR5DqTerop6cOaRzakxWZyIAzmSc6nRZzkddmIGZLaj5MZHbCZ9EaS3GlIgTqxTEPWmaS2HJ6VvzSi6Z4B2o9WbmgQkVC79jQrkHJrReuj@h6WLFuAn0i/l7v9oJ1ESo4SNkvOKnEg0UNo1/CqIXqSOk2COnokKXpy66PK1rlylB9@PCHnZHLerGgH8@uOkg3@q5rXwfezke3m4S3n@AnRg8NIoPDzwduNDlcNEKDrpKhsNeC/BEt4PfcXzhuJ7lx49vEtceO2k8Vct0Lxxo1bJ444J9aYnLry1xCmqyXQlbNmGF4pnW0PVB1JxRaHmen9uOPTw/B@Oz11EjBuKrZuKpA2nJhIjgisVXQtP2cKC4eHPMUL0fJ9m7PNqpbV4qhwMRmIZE6gw6dKbVg84X6@JN4cG1z5hFfnc4WKStoUKnO3fdvnthOS4eKIaxp9AfRLiRIGMwIFqyzMgyM0aR6EQrZtZQRdSvPzsq@7qoGGoYv5hEkGBGlnnTPEbOenOSO1@YHI8WpHfy@fSexOk9uZveju35w2mayRNHe/D5eUmvKhEGAIzIWL2fjKw4yHOGnAQpobePdhFFeDCJbVpg1UZK6wBaF@BaB@QjG775dL6AIPzNIv7fXYBB9L2HFh8ZsycT0Dd9ulSeumh@MB2vAPiBqkaLJmPJhaK9@8C0REeHenhZJpPicvDwCqiYg4HlRLd6B4jvkXlcYTUj97TsqsoD59DkXWXZZXFxEe2et62eMbHaioDMxvAGOT62jDbpq4dlHBUdKT3oA9BAZiGrJ0wxOmSIgMoLRMbIXqnqYrHiIHYoPTQZRxQeLOYfDdxNq2YcBK3yORDXAw2aohNy6UDjwWQw4QeT9ejEwECP8vaHl@QrVxxJeCdDgA/8tno9GyWr3qU@j5UwSw9oEUJYLZllOt4jaLZcsMZnyvDzWHR/TmmUIYxUDUo5YZ0sKnH7rhKPSUUgk9wqeZhI3id0D5a5mKhxZJEK2/m8JmQG847R65mmEsfIfe4sMdeZ0QnohyXmOgtalfM5CjWMSZpuiDfiVrl9oUo2OA/geQXPN/BEhNAHPecCFeQN7dpgyItC@sYgZrUIn4aJtmiMi2p8HjEGJQVuHMi9DdM0F6ZpzqRpJtIMa0AyyRiQZCaSFKWAxXNXEfSsznCBdsYg7LnD4y61DR/HNTyce71J2@mynWXpq3QZFHLaSpf3FFDK6Xa6vEsOP10@Icdluvw1OKK6lf6ULgfVAgE8eCXHU/QXKhzfzXR5R1FvpSEeDx6kq6XLYZkCzBP@Shy55cOrLTHr74ajqpaV5UZllqHE@PBwMVuNZpa@Bfjnx//y8@ohcKnKiisEjB2QRKMRazF4OtBsaD332vKUec1HORiaEuMb0RgKhGeqsUEVlJIR6aN0Kp1URpwwDKXBR3gCgag3y/MpYvpMz@w@ckTqIKFUyMn0iXsa2QNthcIbABwfxOlF8YPySqLgBfgwOjHyIjpnyAmSI4pwMYA6hyxk6vv0HZnCsp46wZyXfryEZscIsBBzAQgvJUIb0@lgw6FtSokN3EFSSCgUZ/vseBz8iEqJ0jsVjbSCqJkLgslb5AwVQ7zyq3dlJxYPSUuoIAxsFJq8loXtAuliDIp0XcxS5ZUPSIjpnDad3Gih2O4KJ8FxdZOltmJRMxTE5UmS5kqqSYis4WkMI2PIU4/mZfCMhs/rvgYxx3ipjIIIYjHDVLh@dT/Dfne5/R4Y1AETphKYZ1jPb0pnzes7W9kpyntRsrMFiIFZtqvONY7CFCKWQ@8gZpnfJWszJv7ICYx8nmiIfcraD9gW9gnu4dt034LjQivBu0p6XuLA7GVxMaNmLZLelRYYLRqmJPDwjIeURlm7m1ae8XlFjCHYRsPjswvYSxZwvPAQH2XAm2I5r@XeyKHlVVHdpvP3opkLPuvg4iqx8Mz9mCeoe1q/Fi7RAo/D8@Pdw1cvvoFGd2NjQ52disBaC3Gjdly6c5og7LYUs3hyLW7Oo7UTXdcbLp058uySMvIAY8CgeRsufqKOq0KXxfT5VN2FeBw2xlGB6zKqBkZCK6GpY2CTbQu@8ps4lRVDIAnMW@B3lnprOGuE0oETOufn1Hydn@PinPNz0Yph0YTTSL9JMXFqo5RKrmEiO8ufORQSu/2jPm26CobdxHGPfPUJHjV3MAxih7FGztAOljjgqBBtxgxm8JVVHcckDjqhD9GBSzGU4hp2XIslPNKGx0JoHO6kBZUinSVu3uBFPv7AdejcejoLmIx1vFbIDwZcieyRc23Q4g@eCp3EE6OIL8MKZsNch9@x4/O4uOuTBo4D3mSZdaHRPE9xCzoal/aAH2ceLvjwVYpEBNPKLOBxq2f1gaQTkNg5Y8gvbRCa7r59cQHikxeXyvJlLacGRM25ndxOcExnir0xenZ4b4lYCUb3D4nRX2Cnkjhn1WfFdbChtrLA2egLjMXFMQzPUi3Q0iyCgu8GPDa4czMbi7ukTNTZ56q@pJxjifIt9raHF8deGU6Mv/T5FB@IFlOUVOtj85TAXEccz5jG8xnDIz4lcdZzlaYpNVyiNlDklByc/YlOaeBZqK5zOl8/YfTM4FBSBY/DLUuPHNJAuBSMmXyRDVi6DlpvNM@mhmtTHfYFWy1KdBmTS6PMnADAwaf4EtghDKJiPvgyP6Fp5C/a8hc4qyg9SqFS5OKH8QPpRjcd1xOJN1sS6HC9q5jC5NUieCnFXrB28OuTIOvYG1kHCudQsqTIGUCbkVWZow7jT0cX0ySPuIqexZTFmbpHgtWA5TefvX7b8jyHwKQrFwS57@IBuHztceWO1cC0HBjXHCYWAyPR8dWdHbHojV/AmZVf47KtMk@EGhwND4RGfV@ZVvg5PVjjSQ9cXM1WaC90J9E6yR5GDslYsp27CKBmiAQd1RStGfvCL8MXaMgGKIFNtMxBId6o99JGHMHF13iuRqFZibVDih6nBgns@KCPOsDPrEw3qDyGiNQuQyOpzrO1CpVEfCDOHzi0/FvOaTJFFUuVEVMSBS9N9A8XzEq0Sj7Qe3dccWHk9c3C@hYtumZOdpjtN7aa2RWzKjNraBtO3x951@3LC7d7BRYGG3xojc3Jx28ZK60x3JlSfMzPDtDXq3k6HmCDztfYKtCekOB0DzqB4kxmjLYj41khacbCzUqVJTw0AD5Z/CnLlRkpZSv9QAr5yut@Y71ZdaqFSr/hNCtOJqMOM9VhRs8o6PFYVyugqPlYTWPYpKWU@RX2MljviAdA44Cs22FHrmN23bTP6Brv@EQg7UILKlDfGMTr0xV0VVwv7tNBeTL6iYo460VXYE7FtN0AbjgZWKhGw6WiPRfkF38ejdbXKrPhmMNHj3Bdc0UYtPEM3EiDUatnm6CeiJ9ol@Aax3JZrNQ3Gcot6C70s7knpwUaMAWDK0Go6Q4mIrLNQc6DvGzHUNYUbPrU7EMgA6gWyOQ5XtfhARgH4exNgDNATS2YyqlC9wvLCVsn3FyhVnDpOVsKwoJtGAiPckObIc7BZqStE/DYZgKUFiYzVSwDJt@GjSsRyL6rpXnQow@j/oDMA43TKziCt@SdDwzbC2Nq/ghvHlWYjsywA6KxBNBxi3v6rsAajRdNUBY4GkEz4pgfxHdEB8oDwaaBtyGDbsQZIcTXdinOI35/owINJh/t4mSIuJQNVRQ1MA7PgEsP0mVGgxMV8KLmpxIL/QChmNcFwX0I7hvD7oLgLuIe@YuCPQjGWx0XBNsQzBeqzA93IZwbYgsAhjj0BuJ6PnTPh4bdU/gqa1yffcsVtsIymYCxoQgwXjC8PJLxmVivzpZ46XBhS4gX1E8SKw6AIq2IyoPvkbRQKJ4RonC5iKXJecJu2L2JiRErYPE5pQRqF9NXVxL4WYwAqH@gStlseJA4L@0wown50fjNXhC8DTr/06e7KBOCmJQ/vRlIHy8hHByN5ZBzK8LDT06MypVH@igizY8j1vPHtVtguUb5CCplMVIhvG5F9bpjg20JUVW0ciJv7Ieq7Enk0/CbrBxqj4iPvFrcz8fijPRgN5VqZJa1Iqf5cK4aKPcQ04AWuRUpC9y8ZVRm2OmH0LkkdA2gQ25OyZmZkBlRSz83sw/LTQroo0pNvKlwRWuCaVgTBM4hz@DlGtcJHNlyusz98T4xO4nMXoCMb3I8BwTDbaABW7ZAjQdtou1ofKEQ6PlCcS1L4/4c5DZiU6CsHsKnf4DKhYwTTfYIr1hJqiQ2hzUz4GG@kV@16So3lT2u6ednrsFXmqWfpJFGNitPJHVPoJUsswILd9NU2O39eui348xNVHwJe8dXFuuKoNADSXyICN4uYPS9QpbMQrHJEhxHEkgz3NMk0c7Q@Y1SNN9xHvgEY2G8bi@0wJCqSjIcaeYIgwAwlOOxssLmqkWqU2yJPR8Gxk02ssLwZjMuFWCyV6S4Osfu3D413nHfcD8PcSQegssL0cL0AsrsTmDbghkcxNPMcyxmzmTkJ9TpC9dtK4HBJAwGwhAsmwagLN9jFJpV3LyMkofkhNHLLsTS66DdrYDPkvCidqVC97QH9hkSsXJB1aaC1SZm39g@XbxH4dgaQVLBlBCOJXHtw8rT/ggdmkCP5kYKND5uFKPtxELPU0ucUA/yjuHguB2dYEZd620Z/cOCQJgadLSjTcdUBrdzRhn4xmqx5fgm3nWxK7aGNnFY6KLXDt30kJrtbRmTiY7u@E1qKT/yvXzLdvKWcwVGdWsipcLhrTJebprbxNFbvKJUaBMaLKcBIRATKClMTXOsayW88hTHHiS@UZAGkHQJT5egwfyeddUGq58vox@4/ph@J9BZKGijwdClEJEQbShkn@xP0Sb3Ak3tih6DIGeb8EQwCk76cN8JH7fK6dxA0vHkDDWGooExSeHKZ7KM5YeEimG/RlPyNcswu0gEyt4n3p2C4iJJvpX8oOhxAxyyAmcUwdnjS38HNI6HSZB14k/oHbKP7zo6uA@NRKLci36KROO1GIJ3kKOQ47Acxt8GBnDGPzo53d07PtbE2c18GgGnHvgwM67boF2E4jJzMcqKUwi4h5MXyiPMLOLm6VUj5KR/iUeYrGATVoVrZCfnFW4S5TnI6fQ2k40QXuXgxBKagxZvPvKyIJZaD8COQt5F0ZRYtFwQLQCOseLRvdwwTBNX5760@i5QvGP1ekA058WjiB3oRI4E6WfC9P0GptkMiefhuZnwXCJc4@GcqAhKM7teBFSOA8mpmwjulskRWHYmrSqDTB@8oi0/muvF6K7cBetr0EmzI@BaWJRcKsOA7URALhbybk7p85ClRJxQwMPwBg8X8l0UJR9SmYB9mkwfn5IoIIsWxop1JFNSqjl27wkffgxDSMMy3OvCo2N5k9jxSikGRIQ6yYGawHvpsdrWqhGWjB5oHKozcm37qayJIaknyjQZfMB7pmLNqSMxLlGaGWLcmFoSSIeCl2IoCCcKGgtqbi2IPBGRJzG0CLUUJCsF27eTFRyyNl3FqziE/gl/gsqeJC6AS80PfMQpH/PM84mwJINI6S7J89mU1CZDb2RxT5GpO1qRKO3JNMb5SuKViz1Qs4uaIkzT4tN1HXfktJdCPRFXFIGmmOF7GCI4HQHogfguKkIMvJV@k1@RvjT6YBX2rDGro01t0HlLUmIuFC8r9/EUMzx0k/mjwaBni8127Jpm28RRRMUSTgxFGGNGgyYd4KodDp9Fl5i7hEgaO0TM1za/FFwE@KOLC37DM8MrJEG14r3t9lCT6s6EXz6Ne9OKfEZSXBuPCrgH3b4YEbzkeO0JL/TWpOAEHp7VDq/f4jZynJXDm6WhSStL0o9Gtnm58yUrFgobemFVj7EsGKouaKtrdId1YCIFAcWCXiiU9DVJ2nEHE77eRDFVxLWWQ4RZ9gIb@jcgm3jjumNJdWgxCBCP6/Qt78pqa5J0bLVpDLg1Io6gKNMd6k6w@R59wLbCQ4jwFnQ/y686BwnDJ7bP/EABk1Y7ZyWc4h1YXt8e8olg98rGy9nDae2O2@u51zQQjTPKnB8YqW8NgSkrKkuSRIcFCFrIdqE9/MANQ9xEbbTcKzrcQ7AB7FQbz0Si@VkJd7Yihnhi/BrbGCWQntkz7D6K0xwCcOtLxIGAAMhae2Rad9IgERGfSUNwxXbbNUd4XIIRlEwetJ9LdQWqu@XZoH0jBlOpULQY7VDAp88PTtjJ4f7p2/rxHgP30fHhm4PdvV327Bt2@nyP7RwefUOn0rLnhy9Au5yw@qtd8H11enzw7PXpIXjI9ROIKVOAVH/1Ddv78dHx3skJOzxmBy@PXhwANkB/XH91erB3kmUHr3ZevIbG@sssAwzs1eEpe3Hw8uAUwE4Ps5RqEE2K4rHDffZy73jnObzWnx28ODj9hlLcPzh9hYntQ2p1dlQ/Pj3Yef2ifsyOXh8fHZ7sMcyYtHtwsvOifvByb1eD9CFNtvdm79UpO3lef/FiKqOHb1/tHSPxiVw@2wMq689e7FFKlM/dg@O9nVPMUOTaAeYBgS@y7ORob@cAHXs/3oPs1I@/yQqkJ3s/eg1AEMh26y/rX0LmJOUerkC57Lw@3nuJRAMnTl4/Ozk9OH19use@PDzcJV6f7B2/OdjZO6kw6cXhCTHs9cleluHtNZQ04ABuQTi4n70@OSC@Hbw6hTbj9dHpweErFQr5LTAGqKxD1F1i8OErnltg0uHxN4gV@UAFkGVvn@@B/zHylLhVRy6cANd2TuNgkCAw8TSeTfZq78sXB1/uvdrZw@BDRPP24GRPhQI7OEEAwInpvq1Doq8p11hOQBd3grBKgeRmqTjZwT6r7745QMoFNEjAyYGQFmLbznPBcw2PzZ075XbnBN7sLJ8YCrn75J6dw909sPj4gX5y5P8aGp3N5ORdIgwamjAQXsUsKLVV522rNbo4t52Oi13zMBqfwe77F1k8G1PFC4TOpLtuy@MT5RQhlTo/f1M/h37uyfm5mn1IzAQZ98UQW@PvglJFHnuu0aZufmJsKc6o2mNxAE@Wn4YRH2t5HA4@qCyfb1siGi4kQcTBMJE4KQqQtVEz0goTw2GxJGmKOTlWRMeYTQ8WBdObrg8/zqfohbcNMQ9QznzdQj6PfVgiA4@jYyH9kAid1CaOa6N1AHaHktR8y7q8UArx5LDLLwao1CAOwQ6hG3ihqPdEb1kXU9Fz0/GJWFwBRMZKcEZPcHYOv/sb3wTLmCgXzaOcKXxojx5qQA0lBEahypOi5UVi9YnymEfHTd98rFCthOe70BltL@s/PniLnblCca0y5f889Od1C5cC4oGD0N41KF6THs@bHAAqmI3dL2CJPeFTqvl8LA5YZWRPhsB4gFAXga7tNrSp2FR3LWrW8dgifoZDPD40xp49jlMPavjL4/rLZ6/390FzIrVrm6WN9YokjkHyhj/O8uc3mA4d44vcBSv62gYzjYJitWQH7J79mRMMY0cuYukhIB6gHhQaeeLd5@F2Zm4j8EPP@DAQZtfHY58cPPlMxpObPJnhoklrSQrkdW7NFAKgJLKqYm76xpgsfANMJZIBk29d7k2o1Mb4g7jD6h9U8TBDQoCEiFn9wXACkgudC9J78n6wCpT6NrTEC0E0OZDjgRGsQeKMQZ1JS2NxiSS9CdmOlSLYtVjQWF@p2CkmELE0TUVwch6dgwlJHLl@UIO5pw0@PxbyBs5vxImNGITnb9WHJ8DG/TBmLjhRkY85i4ohMDdrVSiix4/DlLYZDqSqgig@/p88zy9eG4gUvqCBTSEOVh6FfA5DaBD6aVplN1xS8agVxFMREiveQXLnZUdgqQTn1Ij34Fg/xnFFp/yR13WYhhSAfBOAhOxMsOl34gfh/6/Ikzn4t6HDCdgjbpEetp2R9UBOElbOK@i9ElPs62DFWGyZWsTNuNc3EZrbeMF0w4yJZXhjPrEELBClMwk8vuHnvCpzGIBCjuMa8fqLpypQJe4a0HN6SnX3EZ/p9xyzP1CCU1KDpmIGbzNLNlc2WCKHLyqfwi@wWHIv8NC7p7T5lnQGdrhAi7Um7Atf5jgyOukczHR@hQY9wlpOools0IMaHolTQVStoPKPxQqjqJVpB6G3YIouPoE1nA7Bgx4TCj@YAQkUCK19imdYsA3SrCGhc/ONy@9plJ@JVhzPMAcVSO0yO6XV077RoT4zNkViqTOuqcYkEc8XbXGQZssaXmNz0ePYaYl3hI0pX9Aqc0xEjEWGZkSgfFUNuE6N7HVIPQ1ToryG1L92Lh28O8TiQ1wBhJY4ljO@L15jLw06obP3sHzLUeIZZGstmf6BQ8veTT5fiUNz1HOHVLCn/4UfcQQszmu0LqEdirhkmJfoKQcyal/n7DE8KK2cyHlw0CT0GegY4XlG/@3CDgHKytQaWCafOeEgUpk3ZNUvAvMFXbzuhq5v0CXGmauQKSAOfHDBrDCDkGS0m3CR5mxtI/rCvQ5FKUWLT8tgOV1fay1j1DecjtG3exNadfrB7Tp53xn5A20wwdtQk6OBdBcKwAHtQ4u9tZ22e@2zZ1AdcCDp5NXrk6PkwF9s5GuHj3wx9hWkwZ5RytIM@g5uZPHdzhCKxqqwibhryouGe2icUIy00LDWBD1wt5BHAgTp9kPL@MtXr9mXlmN5YA8e0ZpL9sI2LQfUBxhTtArT73JNg@D7mPqJSJ3to@1CIzsVZtk0qBOO7UkiAYEti6KlQFUEgj1x1jWOzU9A1GNjgtpshqN8tYNBpa47EJs1cNAUjU0@xNkZ9bISHqj99uD0OXbGececxmagWQvG@nAskZtOfT5YC5nxDGc4AaZI04M3QPZ9Yzcao70agFFazE7q1PXxyqE2Dvv1fMgqXhQmtAC1IFBVLfsKT/ClYbiHlBGtsxXDZhHfKmLTa1bcvyNUR6L0pKj0sniQu5ZlpS12aqHssqOeYUIPi52MMPrqKtiBz1x/iKAv64wVirqu5/RVHKJ9fVLXqCLgNzjWVZIOXh4dHp8CI8W5RYFghG0mMp9OUuWrsYAdOTxPFXL/HhVyAA8as/iemIcmeHC4glzhMxZyWYayNw0c7oUc@klzmIZkcUje9eg0V9ysAyKUqI6Qqn@NypdPjVBKMexZOk9WnAjLm5aQTtpiSRHeI209kKsezoe@p8jkBwrAGpMfxPKoZ9AWZxFBmfStfki9PQxad4MDSNMH0YYM42OpIBzpbBqtJOCeGsfTtnCNhI9HOvX9K9MD3WJcgcjhEpZgxxLIDOkmNcyN0bJ7NtQBoMvsutjgcHUVFAQNQcSPqZWoxMMDELFBIlrmHCEFtavt9kNQTpUkhTv0hP/An5guS11ANxt7Wv7Astp0fNVowM9nwnANankPWg6@d68cHdwkpQq0btIDZYPn5IHuG/VwQz9uwGzxMpeC3IBUBXs@T7vYreeIIEcnQ6qkeIyuMqeHnWU4z6tSsePt2RhXRUYs2H0JKAZZnJQCqqC8SSDIReKSpRuzqLynN2diRDoh0h8kAxAXn9W1kgEBesy7cM4AcCGthgRM7fsMiOF7lrg7MQaWfMH84rpT3NOm8DxC5iZqyMx9G88152MDLrtw8ReBtYBjfI7QojnCmd2keCuoDvimIfVZSIAKT3WLQRbn4MzNxbk6H2dO4BSTlQfOFe2nw1gkFjwX/IgOF/QjMiLK/pduoHpp11/P5RNMYe4vem4LD9METQGp4WOSjQo27k09sASj46F8Z2fyENDtIEuCdLG3KbBd2DbUD6vGtoMRi9qZwwtKBFR5XaLtY4zaLqpO5MQfUaPIKSdOFEWrY@pIUSSP@4LuRrSyQCl85DKLaiauxInDi5STUfqJKPpUFEFcMkorEaUoRdvHp0oXY6Dqx2cyZ4FdQquSqARYNSyggtQ3xrx3U6DNgDRMg@d4JzYuFptCQBCwYbJwfyGCN6Xo3IzEtD1PI3ilJXi04ltelukc0kLyEKpxsHSP1ABBJcIndDaLo4gMqYIN9BKeyaEGxIh8bVMUJ6apwgzzACmRbQ/3ainxVNQySw0MPmuIUD42bPGkG8QDnKWX4W@FKSKBXJxYDoRnHQhVCIyn8zAa0JXlxRLowYIUtcz0FlNwUIIS19@0ZIw3A4qSqFeB5g5xcueM7gZU6M/RUUoS35Ttg13HfbFFiamGEzT48Gx5YeRZY@ie0RwzoaD2JxyxFp78oIlQewjiG1HKzaDVSOZiIfR0UzIPJtaqhFy4CzhgdsinhcCLWxtiHY4hoL7j4DHWvcBBYsG6oAlO@5xlZKXYQ9qL7po211BJtsWULo@bnaOAk0UeEJedypUUO19G5HC6GZESLWdCSJTYG96dw77gpwtzRKqUiIX8X1TguNwxXrEXwukcThT7IokIcQXlfpdYhMBBud8lFhw4Vux3i0VwwHTIWoo/LReJkuAswEWJosdAY0pxHRQEjONQ4ykoImjSjB8wY/WUOdTGtKoY65RmTKWQReI8uWQa9BjzghHXliXFEZjXCEujGeUW2jjz0mqHx2SI3IddpJqcbBJ4aU6fDoWZDlKgMmqqeI9JGAE0Nh8EE33mPl@7SccMpXmHhfqgeJTqRTe5uzeBNmhVCuqsQRkcqRQRvz2X@Nzs0VZRF6s8e2lPuLpMUI0LnlyvjdCyNGfGV7qHqkyMqmTuYiWUZPECTLkHYco9AFM@hklU7FVoL8mZ8vDwYOs@FGdnszjo8Q46UgIHaNq2jYPY2A@@Nib34VwCYytFa@oMvqosjBDZyffheDKNgw5r74azccKza@Co20fLc6ePSlvI2aSszKEopCo1S1YWySKtTf1dAReYStS31S5bXTvsCaTuL2l@poSIjEuJu@EkUCp51FGILKr/@gL@ZWPFmqwPnPDEMAxYy9JnVgcNGcFHmPhWsTBCTJEl@6EiIMmIu0OnlR/1VqdPmsBT6BdGU@/NyVM@4BMbdNIha1xjJSQu6MJFyilorQL9Nq97dm/6qbnpD9wB2DiduQQQfB/H8fmg1JRKj0zTqa71g9qyue3ZbL7idtvUgXEPr@SPZ7JehKzjxnSo1I51LVr/uzCLvAQl8FtY8o1ARhYQ@cVcInGi3RCDW8wZ9VuWJz2kqvMYGj54H2mx5EpSKsXqJnSZxcFFdG0UnalsiSTRDEZB8NlogPM1Pl/ciZUbx8gsLsDTsHipPUFrMiZBY7R9y3DESUaiwbzwcP4ihM3imeq4uYtSsB0TGO1bseHP9/yikLYlQnBF8h1srcwve5RqTFNQkY1SEmRxW1OZJPu03HeBgRNaNQRVnjZUAtnBydAVbpkLewkMc3X@ENhDrKe7DCIQ4kVJig7vFOq7ZbS8mJmjQcjKsGgewMp55lY4yv0Ac2vyUHPrvwInpwtUirmF9SAa2PK9Sm26k0@35AanZffnHN3y5nR/P3HgSWsS9Ar6llcqFAp4CM7MlXg4QYGzxLabT0LncUw8P7j@ynvTymPU5CV4c@/AQxoAFKFxagLlBKcmRtDexE7lwvEcB3flfPA5JD@Bp81oGacdLm5/c0rCRyiReVaZvccMYv7es@CqajAceZdBYAnWm0FsNEOv5GCZHLAHPTp4ok64JI2QUb9Z7FrAiY9q7UZ6JO6FpHE@vMNHvYm2IcrPrV7PzbK3rtdrL8l8d2gywv5@PEKBg@BSQl55fLpTIsusK7sXu1cDQWL3wPOLmfDSXT76SXuZPGuAM2kKtmPH1sXeeKDIjXcyCCZkOYPZzDC5idt7LmRoomSaQr8fLT/GDMh@EHTfGCgm8WkaGNpAsZcqcgFFq3jzJl8djOMpO5BlXMyhJEBUfi4M59n90MjU@eRqH1zbUSDrGCzhdjna@k3FSzlZAB4yVz4b6x3kYYHjEDThuYkPi3FbwUOnfvsPjm7jyAFubqQx3nBLbOy8sXg@gsF4rFnsatjpQPXiI/G14KixAB2pypxOqxSQNaJgPevbEdgzSrrji2PvcKnNycQxE4Q0is0sE4fjVX63PEpBDRTVD/iJyya@zkG13h/R5SqRPqNhOFxAMat3MMI5RpCkL8zqt9dKvV5ny4NMhtXrz8CRy7H6szrbRY9nz9guvD/D98fVYqlU4SvndtUb8HwWeN6yZ4CDmiC8yG0XXiGM7mfCrhQW8XK@upytLJ9Xt2sVP9@oP2vm8xfg@rvf/@nf/dM/ydfFy/f48oxeGu9CIE3T8svmzfLj2wq@N3ab6eVWY3nQTF9UUMpQ3b/2fKNnxLaJaeY/yGW6wc55U2Vg0arVapqlP33irrNh5PQiJ958EEU3eoOuQdEZYahV0/X048fg2q6mf5JW8eQO4W@E/h/Bn6moy2m@mFhL08f1k52Dg/jlQuGlpR20NHHC/f9r71p62zhi8Nn6FWMJsaSNZFlJmkfTBEhuObQF0t5kw5LXK0eALC20UhMjUH97yY/kzOxq40eQpkmRQwJZ2nmQwyE/cjmciSanzRbFjIgat@zteX/kDg/dSd@N/fQ4oftUHixP0bU5Y1Qm87dO0qhD9j2yVDGwpJ8iwUjyniQb7bK4QHqRJSjhNySDcaN75z9L6hz6uE8Kj59/LodSO7LdmHyaLue6veiPho9/Oum3Wi2MjOzc0xRqDqPl4X7jNEqWRaabVNTLacsQ7dwbT3nkqENmRqt1L6V5HKRax2GBCyWZYNQrbLfaUWkMR1PK5CrCPX9/rwPa0JNlbGExOzLmGxy3ZmxwddvEPZqAvzbdfXS40rcpN9VeRTcIRrcHc8WT6tXyvkBnuFwed8tbh2mlEkO1Q2EeefeQoBdKo/1NcGNXqMZ6xY97ZG@W9MT9cn51MecbN3FoonhP2ok439XFmi@sKiKPIC3Psim/@JQdLQsWDu0BGGZ8FnaR8tsFLkI658q7AvjsrmVCkLQfGOFoHY4pn/nuzBdyVGA5pY9k8LkgotwpDTG8j@JOIlD8Ug0lYqS96YEkJ@yay5PMVfo7pNlCPDjJWxM09nYTLvOutsQLPZW0fMQZfcMTuwGgqzupib3iU3YIVV6yC8pBEWIKP3mIgrWkGq7ceL4Y1901jSxFDCnDPJBMZNJYfpiZvnjFcHLot9kVari87WKyVvbmy6KYaaKKLhOycOSU8Ip6PW43ZDCVlvg27iT3Oyqmz0Qp@0ByznEwqTlCoxORKgWlBzl5kzMPJS@uVcrHxZXsrHLPsvUslaNSMvq@6eIc5UD4W6mb8smByHmQdFBbYIxw7PQUqmaCYqlDP@ATn0rm/f/OQ@8JeGYpRjJfq9qSj7xw@NU5DkwKPXpJQAdlpugcEZxSDu6VBHOeXczWpTY9OXSt50uFiq2xnjf5GBmPEXcrnOXcILsO26uEsfLbkrBZ8dpvpGifSnZ1vewZMWzVJBfLtxSSUDjj6a58eH1k04lnTTuY2Mfbt1deIRhXtnWzQuRY1iSIqgurcO0I6FynKPoiwUl@dKDaosqT/ogvBa5wg9RpZRsELXxU6j4SYBbu2JJDR1XYK8slkGBHeZu82Ey3NZfc/5vjlpbybMWlZmnz0VMsB2SjQzL5GT2xSAO68V3W7sD3mQF1Vr8znF9abeaE/CVJXS1KfI98GNTPozKUka4r3AdSyq1g2agdr2WlqdEbWp@UW/fbUrvho1Vw6ERIJ@9qYQf9dU@MOVlT61dKM3SO7M@t1ZDQEgw@M91WR1kO8zqZMns41521eVicbZ1omA9vWt5oVmTBqTFx5@gLtYf0uTjfv4ZJW4RwXm3WyzfrL4/pEbvDbGZT/yXuqidcMCEYrBBh0h3oJ/o4wr3XX8gtYD0wI0UgJ1UmRUafGw1BHuphNn8tLl4vP3SOesfN42Zv@PhZtwk/2eOwVlqQZ9RKM86oXrGXkKnvSZZYM@T@ykSFr85m5@eEOPTGBWqqo/mfTrXbEUfIP3p1V/RhaptQ4lkz0uVFnxYRXyiv8TlfTS4uJ/j42/LP1eTqDRkh/Pn7QtbzD@7vLRkjvnkVv7yVPfrqnKBGc8t@cpCJW5GIkPmEkE@6BjRYZ1IqwcOFGgZkOwyQMT39RZnYiA0x/RK78OgZdpMWdSwIpZDc8LHUBBzDBeDjCeSnncp3JJvqwhSoZycf8ZM4BFUAyT/YSZ7oW2khUH/uXnKbUkm/UFENgtfBaNKq5@YkoEfmcl1PylJOPo797IuxOjbr9N3p5Wa@nillO2QZXdyo54QVG76WRMnkKoJcDW/2gg9A/YIfUV7ZMDqHDKu8i@jgfkcz2qXBl4GiClxQJ8x6ifxHYzfoR9gxgAZ1VaSC@4NHkI@j7fNr1kbQ/UtzNbjAOhdxi5YD9DLPI3dDKg56O@s81fsl54PnQUzhaSQ562RRzdt4jXmFuQQ8lIlf3K/hs3/PTq58wyw7DVwyv1TTqEWHBV8f54d77qiPtwWxV0uSgsbF8tKyLdWdiJzX6G5o2kF8gvy/dlhv8NxK6C9ilZ3PjLHLfmmjlcChHYyL2OlBDCxzvAqgNQYjMZKAysm1AprwuRkVrWRbX6M2xCmhJ2XOVZBtiMlTWqPeqIsd49nzMGLnp66hN4@A8CjJ1LkpVbVuwbDpy2CO6gULZnMtY8oYsrtgQANmrXHCvRjcyKhsl1HDz2OUzKuOT/LLF2NTmQFlLm0bjTrx9apDD4zGe93XCtjRS2DcvgfClT5qgC7ea0YTq3ZHC2jI/pmB4cS9uiC1WMbCkjUwCd@J1yMOZFGpDeUDcXKkZrPKfiZETOiqQf8I8rKWwvm4UgSEIOug4R9CJQjmBvjtoxFam8wNWt2GvpkdSCpRZ/hk2MUgtxipUbo3487wXtQgv4qZ7pS5YIMCyJG4Uy0VcrP1g637RFi6RF9tSJo0cghKi3pO8pyP7N4UpR607IYtR927rvvMADViJQ/EBnGcZ9Bq7NEUBGlwwhYNhtb3NcBbZERGbkdmJJwbCn@If2iB7m8p/m08LlCS30uABwhHhg4Yn3GvusCKEJBKiA3avle0idX@wHztKAGqAS6CtSVJNgs@VFNdGxDyqwIrXVhMEVA7iirWRk0tQuRatc1cR873TuZ4dZSlHAj3UaqiG8WDNewwaFu1aJ6WlETxXZbUVUzOwYHTuSFkXcEYtY5@iVEyjxIzjheinKuiS0qIvwTj1aTQNvGoL6@NP8gD@kTYnQf1QITVa8AhIUIzCHzfLDzn67mDptfxhwm6WFZKCYAncn@dFXkMs2nclaFVft4gpAjofT9SeqeVuK2o@kLp9bIotvjJUGxxbHuuigFHG9j6SD1@qeiDEjLB/rgkLrO0J/YXYQr6TwSU7@2arH25MNL2xVoyR7shyaNYHxZrmK/n4fUj@3Fikybn52SON3wa/2pNXfBBfNxUF/FZGhVwKe5mMM1Jl@FVFZKLyVOpembaOvhlDo5Z5P5a/TFwaqoFm/aoO6QXoWYLv7paplIBjJMAOTiAvFL4tUNxi9ghkoYj/lMLqexNpR75VHeyUOCSUx1WadD5gAjBWK9Xk/WtIFZ4JSen292Cq8HyXQMVOSwOG3zn5l0h2W1wWXJrXNZKENNOAjxLWjlhi4ef2cfXxWkhQEv9NP3Mm7xREcCHy0EspgWaX/XiYL5qrfiV2@fDvh/w5Vs1DMk3D18Sz/60DGKSAGLSWhATHtBWKQfe0M4/D/VA23YBDzlR2CPjLcvj0b6x8Za14xUZVxh24TltvMSw/HXNsOv3S23hBVUHRPyxdiDWtbKnx03d22PX2d3Qst7BDD/8YYb/z2b4Hw)

This is another addition from [A Brief History of 2D Programming Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829).
I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/tormaroe/ropy/blob/master/ruby/ropy.rb).

There are two ways to print in Ropy - to use `#` instruction or implicitly print top of the stack on exit. I use second method as it is standard for Ropy - 
see [examples](https://github.com/tormaroe/ropy/blob/master/examples). `#` does nothing if stack is empty, so `#` at (0,0) is harmless.

Main code is on line 3: `18&1&`.
`181&&` → `18&1&` for Pip.

Normally Ropy IP wants to turn left. So when on the first line it moves straight. When top of the stack is 0 IP wants to turn right, which causes problems.
To remove first `0` from IP path I changed `0|` to `1&` in Japt code on line 2. Second `0` is on line 1, it was fixed by adding spaces to line 2 under it so that IP 
cannot turn right. So there must be no nonspace chars on line 2 near pink code. Important spaces are shown in gray.

[image]

Labyrinth broke, and the easiest way for me to fix it was to remove `*` from line 4. So now Brat comment starts on line 14. Second `*` is for Agony. As in [Zephyr answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153962),
two new lines added for Brat forced to move `/` on line 1 to keep Kleins in the same place relative to surrounding code, other 2D langs were updated accordingly.

Comment: What is this madness!? A 10KB, 181-lang polyglot!?

Comment: VIP score: 0.001686

Answer (score 11):

## 185. [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), <s>9888</s> 9260 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print((1/2and 9or 13<<65>>65or 68)-(0and eval('\'ppp\'.bytes.class==Array and 4or(\'_\'[0]==95and-91or-93)'))^1<<65>>62) #wWWs {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ye{--}besizeString tnd xfmain=los1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"cl91/2 <5>6#"5"8=2860ay =+ codefn( );#6and [9]=x 3 8[]p#s
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9SZFVLD1u6d6qklpS3erbFEuVTCbJLJGZvJmkRJZKFz1ro3ceC3u3p3fQ2@Od2z27hgfwAh6sbWAXM4AB79fFYH/DnU/GwHD/g/Y5JyJffEiq7hmvKZEZGXHixIkTESdOnHg1Db/7m9@k8MOO3d6k03OHbGj5Q9by7CvL09izCXtq2P56cVWSEKrmdUZ9yxn6JSnFdMZsx7Rb8M6G7qXl2B8sD/yLjA08t@MZfTbsGkNm@aYxsHzmjoaD0ZC57fnRVhnb77vv7RzG7NtOB8CGljfwrCGFrzH22ukZ/WbLmApZn0pw4EG4z/as3sf@xyEz3X7fcFo@QG4w9tL1fAvhTcv3XYy@ydh43zKnkG4BqOHZ7ovaq8@ngrYZ@xxINAY9a8yMpj/0DHNouw7ypMBOX70@PZ6Koevsq7ODg2nfIvsy5zrsYGReTgetsteeb/SMafxrrDYauofDaf91VutYjsGK2rZWnA7cYM88YybKJvMso9W2e5YGBcJyrGv1BpbH0Ie1XY8dAkm9rcJW4aIWxdRMjLsVBSbQUi059tzWyMQSHHYtyBiWOiL1JROoqLKBqGsaOliKyOBggPrU7VtxZvjMsawW8weWabdtk1NnjYeW40OCvsZsYN613euxltWDCBF2M8t8l438mFezZ3Q1U5Mwd5gK61/2mM3MwYDxINazgaSDwhazsC6yDxDe6/psPOgz3@5D8NB0223LYh@sQReiSy1XYvAxB1PZCt@WLYBxrIA11gBqFbLGxUoIfAo4dO0ZA2C/L3gwtPvQZuxh2meW4dvYKiGKbzkt4uogbK8uM5w4w9iVDbUGsj7yCLdveVRuhBfK2LMApRG2GOXas4fATeRGjR1bhsfOPMtSk203kSQk5mIKQ8yIRoW6s5PePzpIQ@HyGJoxgML0Vs9@8IVkMK3Cli/K8K3Iclnaf7XHbpbP0c2bKlSAgacYKqt8y/z8@bkF37HezHe8WwmwSsCVHsu7g2HeyA2AwNwQCMwb6ERX7qqoDXqxhNnOVFnEqhyHakFpQA1mX2UpZ@bI81AcRUw1LiHTPdfpAD8hs97IQX44bKMARWC6IE2yzLoCrkHzpTJyr4nDZ10bCs3HIok1Cy5UiaEgVqEaC44G6fpub0RwENMfYl0GrkBUxHjYZl@xtmH3MAqEIypOtWf5o94Q44ycFpY8CE2rpbGADNNtIVDfvYLkDEBKHlD1@7F2SUQBMBSES1nFoO//2Z@2Oh3AUzNN12uJ6voVa7kmiX@DiAWZyrDCuo7RI7IALoup8@iQwJXRs1vGEJN3JiIJIoJSvXZHvRZzIUHv2oZW2jWuoGVD4zKHFq/kvMfIsr5xyaWJzWsuZLxvNKFgKQFKm7KdY093oZRMS0pRncn1R8P2FssN9lnaz79VnpSUJ0vnFhCnaurKcj7fKUOF01bIC97Sd9Wcr2oJ8ekPDd@1W9JgMuy6TpHlTCabFXdgOUo6gSOdTXvNtKqhlFPUsl0xtbbttJT0DtTFKiScVstmxazbpUZ5Kno8SUBzjWiwuVqKqcoSiBxqFFf5vmE72mDCvsoJVyzM9S@Q5RisxbyRMdN@V9wjRT0m1ksXKwjIIc3vWdZAKWi6imIC4ebmGwPm5XQKh8hwyW5k0ql0Jp51wgA5TWQUG@uZ7aLY6g262FkCUxx/AD2Bh3XXNKD2@NghDEFtybIm1WvqRUCykEy8ttKexZogSIN6RE2SNzmMn0NBKTBETSjZkq1WrCGDEIC2PPRnpHHPvYYEiSbsZkB0OJio0YGigcg8IzWeEZ4S@SSzdOmAQEFsTYtt5Zo2NAJsbiDTRZ2P5Q3AV4scBrDxRhKTPX1jAlhM3q1GDYbZbWhLfRAP3oSZFsocED4W71AwkRG1Px8UNVTZCrni@nqyjc00saGXr@V@BEL6Q/7OloSZryWUBuh52tY16xlOZ2R0UFd0IIphmtZgKAQV5MQfgiia7m/IMyc6T83vSstPp9OmTiRQLaI0UMjz0hNdoYHSRWiLuR4IU2YIfZe1bA/EUm8ynToAXE0lLr9DkAQB7@QFJAQaAFQya2yZoyFINajA113b7EKdReocLhd5JzSdPHjFUwfJnmuHSSMxevVxUdLyoReSsRBFDkt0Fg90roiqmvCgwo973I3Z8PtzELshidARxHy1vKFB3bsHZ9913DlIgZEhWgRJhvByAE3sFBVK6LgCtYsaa6hlhkUEZQZSA1o@1L/ucDjwS9BP2MPuqKlBTcmfeZPD4ZGDlSU/9Cb20OXuZs9tglj2oX3mgxTy5qhpj6cyRH5hGb73pStQwNo@q0DP/c0Iap2SbvsgMMl/F4FjQTIJbkLBf2UAJCANGKW0fRLFByBUTieOqcgaNSUNGp2cZTI2XFkFB8YK@bLr9lEKsTekGKCmB2MH22mDtBIyn0S@MberC2U/6XXptPbetR3lJr20tJQupasg2ZeWnoBrB11P0JUB1xNy5ciFcBq6KEaWXBhapxjo10jf1gPMY7WBxTbGXumDPVCMeqm02sgadV08i/hUQdSBZAPoHD4AT1qtVNCpqnL1GjKqNdvJ3O@idD41PXsgmPCFcWXwd8GFVWKD3R@4HiqwZexk7@ZJv@JBLwhKq9lVvPR5vXDeOL85b2XOb9NZjK2WjUoTMgXpKX2t47kj6C7V@loppzdUtb4KnWSzki6kVxRlK9eDhAxV/WxLzRic20raAqmtnJ@ngamCP3Wz6xG@cbaoqiGrgA7smEEnVNLazRak31QbaiYNcdV0FoYYlXQaOGMiE3zKNNbMBIOOTr7kjNnNZCSqhq53id8ZsQ9@GgywePQDqL@7py8So93@JUhXZvo9VEVyHtdG4DW/wj1b9Ag1rhI7JI3Vge4WcgC9bSscGTmuk3NGpD@TcuvGE6LhIEKQH/Y9KFftBAwibttjGCBAu58EihD236gL7cKA04Xh8htSTWQGDYdhc9fmakPHvFvRTD@qA6D3gHPQM0xo2El05zI7B4RQz/P5@SFqeQbxtKpEo5r78ggdi2k4yL@WTVr7yPa7yF7QrHAo4bWBq6iyg25gEdcOmQl9fgc4bY3tIdfhoR6dYpTnhq@oqDXWuNaFyh5qDEhUYAOg7tw1YbxjgeaAoXzwyPadK9tzHWSytg@oocKXsQymkM9jL1SjWu2wuLeYv/OQA8dmvPUYb@NYp5lr@ibLO27P7bhsBQCwamoar9iHjgkkgM43hOEl8@0PxKBax4WBT7IOWtjd@6gj6hurofZtIGSe4LX3IGvY/ExHAAvyfHr4o33oIfT1QgHoD94K9AkzGcMynUf0NFkEIOx@Paw3WJI/sgbdiZeoTr4rRpFQn1yLN0w@rjegQwWqRAv/QFHjjZz7QDsPglqBa17e90lDQlNGfJSRyD0og9BORXZ4s4Ecpqa80TdgRQLpTIFH5XsAsvOsO7Iky@y6TD4HDaNYZfmWdZVHgSODoOuCqpyDpCyPlLEwmrBDSkN3BFpdy@rZfXt4SOaunoOqS9QtB6G70MAiBMe2NZTEeCMSr2iSimSt0@Hw@2PskHzJoid7dbS3f3FcO3tekfMj38v37CbU4JZ10QfFs2f5Mpv@pNiJBchE/A@XvRPXHVZ4cV322L2fFMYJor/Yu3hx@OykdvI1J4LQ@HZ/1DOQlNLyFABGP6XgoFXF7IBtz@2HGrkvCmJ5FVlvJQzHODwVoWsYOhJm45j/Bvr30RSsmVLHNFnO5a@hpwDcREA0D1Mf1slkEJLMxaGngNwilGgy1rxm4LmNnqGxOGFGjdDNC18cSWC@0Qu3iNx3Rv4glrMbXSf/q2G7jb126F0k78scVvVe5L1K3tzYnDTzCrbMBM0FDvGtET5upJ6LbyZoLnCIb53jQ@P2fHRTIfNAQ2QbhAyN4XNxTQXMAQwxbRKmuAE9CtuisEXWc5HW3OCFkXhzOAMB/MKFbvOF7dNESrx9SKF6dy7JgY6aUMbkKKQY2YpY7mq@kUuOI6KWC43r0sWhUeS6KGj6OmIJUfQve7Mx26Bh0E8CdIao2RAuMfrNNv3MASgJ@wkIR5wQQK58gTZgNPG4oO9Z1wRGI0FCBtyyHSN/Qg8cE86jJzm6TRDTtNojUIXyoKqj@x6w3PYWQbabTXsRKPAFSQ@ec8C8UXMe22Bk2p0xgLAE44cjb9izWuL5n37cggKYLZ6uMSH1L3RcAN@obrQXlpaIii/0M79kCeb9qGcbxAZy3YfSNNDmbPRCx3zU2I@xXK5reH3UskThQuXEHxB9d9QzTrln9UYtK3jOT4RYnDSz8NiO3accwROHCTQoWhB9ykjE45Oi3XONFmHh6rBtRaXNy8Uac8Uwpm9B7/IAOgNbDosmT4bd0XDEf3G@5L5ytQf4nc@VUrKSFdaNpm7lXd9o2tYd9cAzLkctNze47FCmkbSNRbWdNyI0PeTaPeOSOy/QOZ8BPIue3elYXvBcBHbdBQ2PVNP8NT3uqCpB/8pIYzLuwun1@O8ikGDaO3Qs5pPdo59PqZBURUxoNchanBTNxdhkTzG2ZzQnqKJ3P71mYYKkuIDgqZiZTGEVu7PQAh5Nvw4Gi@NjH0jxt7fnx@bTsZwl8xTXPJ@GzXHzBOVZTMze0@qh57L7Ri9XbMWcC4V4YPqKXHNAabyWM3uGD5VpKIrDuoLio5@7Kjh2RiZWq8h1R/WOyAkmQhbZ1KM4A9t0e7Y/4C1OvCySptPWyAgNzovTTxQV32b52yKVyO/mQtd8geCaQ7RrL6hvDxBw3KSMRvtYBdLcRbwz3Wv8LlQxuu6VxX/nd3of5lL1AFGV61HNsM050VvmfdUVZ0bpZz4XL@dSNTR7c/1L7KXrel3L8VlRKwRGNJyWMno9buM@OzxaXKd9u@f6MEDD37t4AQMx3@e/82tznG224eTI0hh3z48miBowTVhWFhSm0eu4vY2tTt6An4UlPvLa2AOI50MlXyi5dP1@yRUoSK6ji@dCkX@Z9y7vqwxkjvRw2iLmvKO/nSe@hLl7cQZhGIFzkfMzd1DYophano@WFxWAZ3avjUnw/C16lUXcDXqVwYTUa9D/MML2FjiGHle5f5vU1u5OrfUwmTSDdvO@TMQK97JngYSm35kiZcWC/okx9ELh4RKq3RtZI2uuxDhqvrdwedodsuLhRBVENpaFXSkPzEOrUgj1QQweH0Q19t/4dqeAMXo2NPJ7tZy58m4AOvkAx9vH4DhGx2zEjjMaJAo3xruTkXNyN@e6g6Blu60EkRjyqRJp635dKqG2@xZ9F6n4@30XhshuH3QG5wHlL5CSKY7/JhCTT4T5vY02Tu9OvCUWzm@CXgv6B5Sqfenn0FD6MMFTXDS2J@DtbRi9OdZwgr@LuD1PkDZdt/cppQPytGWjWgbKJq41vK@UZnQdMdXNIiuGjxaRZnuR/YL3NWKgCdzDQfXCgj6GLA2pc3hIKc/YWu/otWKW1/vGm9Bjk5HI98zAvYjeE2zcuralbd5JMFdH3abVM/hjvLF2F75tbfUhKtEg0HPJUo/WfW7PjyZEUlMiaDABZtktGKt0rb5Fr3co@Ubr/cgPHguBxi5@5wRrebJOL4g3sKHNO/ibmDuIaUVD14HR1dDwOhYOT3o4qSV8F8nZwOg9l7mHfaNjHdxbuSIrBa6D4oO6yDnfXlHiSxNMiHaPJOEjP9e5tCZ@8JyvH09MKM9R/05s89q5icbQexu2lp9r679H7XO6btfpWl2PGkf4tqh5QI0c8rXpd2UC6O8a/iUu/CKZFA3run6cuz2313sId1EmcgnpuvPttPu4aLsFUT8J78RoQoB43GvSg66bmER9@KK207VG0EP57tAdWDl6WwTaQ@MP/51vej48SvvsjW15LT5rjZZAY2g3exa7toGE9358qnS@YanZcw1cW3iHEg@cCZ4PMVWZrnevHaRjuMPBgB4Xg97Ipx8y@eba822ZJXZAlD6kMthDvmCAV1mr4zbNrn0fSU3LGDr2ZT6w6fDX@dU8KYwp5zbL7aG31rOBV95Ew0pQiYef4uNwfsO3X4itJXcqJLsjz5vcLxySU8Gh@ZVPGqBjkQFGzNrNCaauH1fFBKs/7pi5EJN8C2sUKdOoOOesAmgn@kJzUGIBkGBBb3V1eA@XTNe8vFefWGjIFPPDZNKzY3Pc4D9txbibjOdCvsHoUHk@6vjq/RW32wK9Cn/mVpJah1cQnFjye@51zPAMTd9wxGNu3OKL@1On2ZH1OydKSkx/cVE7OrwfmdmzBz7/Zbl2ca6qMDu3Ows1mT/2FUXVstr89z79ru96uA4aFImc6Vm@iXZwlMFcNnLB47gdkMW5HouAA9i55M9OJc/TUJL9XO6Hr6yOgeuiXti4RKrnz3Z9gHl6VvkhiH8wMnz7ByN3aM3FOT27/BCUL42ObT5PlECAMOCuWETDHwlhiV6zBXHdtX1ajho4FukRUNHuFofTBvdwc9TdxpGYjiTWBrLcIQvWEIYONPljuDE3rbj67g4mD@qSyJYqnnPr0/w5@busC9ej/mDki8d8FbiPy8zjJuX@JfrzGf0T2lgULkH3s2LlFPjZntj/4mvBJrMUrTKjBenBAmWWwmXyI5SYQ9fTGMEpipHJqKrEI6HxueMAWABF23xwCwDfQeSznu0PCdZus3qdLd@MS4WSfssqTC7JrNHgWPFDC9L3xwPao3PCo9eXjUZlOZ3LpZfT506JFdIhuNUDTs8FNxKwbZsenN6IBcwx@FpCdAc5LvMtDn6Xtg@BltECbeU1DHKpx3I9vlCf7wI5w1nv//gXLbGrCoY0PuvbIPOAIbip0O1bXff6CU9XpF4bDAzclYU4oIn0@B6B3G6N@deo1vDNVO41e31wtiW2aIgdjPByjP1vjApeuDi@xgWWQ154nJpwsZxIOIwVZMp0e6O@A4pka9j1NXZq09rJkRctggIXgjlDD7XpVpYdspaFc4u0JJYGkD3XvaS17UjJf/wLvjGFFsaKBYtB8rQhLZYirn/VaTeIabojoDpA8sHyXAGiIJOhmYzQPANNzuL@Ki4XpR0zUCNzwX4RSoZvGtmtnbLcPkvj5kxchl6228py7eTzr@qFRuVb1s9b/@nHefVGME7@LLe94ctZFoCUb7FixYPXITgKTTN5eSzzBMNVw7bQWq55eQCLDF7JcOFwUMdcdyBaDe35oy1uYW0UG5gVdFM5BxtH@rRdkCqsdU0bR2i1noPiA/fhOT40MHhVCTVvdZVlZcQtCLnTIVuHBHHzjQEuvsGQ1tHiJgiMsjxmH1kXK1nOxLWd8MYZ2cN9N/3Ks2CxyWp8SVB@z2qOaB78qqgVVyuUneWLyk6VXJ7VcnH/W/3t@bhYyJ2PN/cbeT9g6vn5@LNC8YfAdRcGN8uP89jy9l/t3Sxr1cLHj74xYbJ8my7zVU8gJpZvjg@P90/PamevT6EUbgPxc@B6fSOSNViLaLVm1@3RzkLgi2db/ifIn/ANwBWFLRtsBzdeq6oUX4hIoILXck5e5s6YaErEvif6vPi@FQufBRAyrW2zoEYdQueEZQiVDbmGmR8NcH8kE3HFHi@qZTbKeGxAIWNwbdkcWUqsklkFmJUDZj2QVWxxZp9wv4dw7F4sd7PtyVwQ5FiYXj0M51mcy4Lbv5d8D6Cj/N3zzbHcnW@CuSPfABr6BnEOaocvXp/sJ6NBHaMnSd3K9rpYgcuFM7Y0bnwINrXRZgUREa0vFZnJFIG/is5shNudmtbw2oJsCeFo9nlkqqFEvyxFFRM4U8GjCRplzgtFIQpQByljtqYWCLftcYzEoI@OobvhWQyFwIEcog4I12SBOUU7/DX8BNlArIJdQdM7JiEu5HXaj6s/2aDFYdawjwZFjmIt6KrCXsdn8B/rlQJXscHGTHRneoPlWBG@PQuGM90QVi3zPootc0bIy5x2OaQXd5cDTa33Bg1/aJmSWAMNvXTPGOBWVgH9CoYcJfbNyKUNF4EwCfWLa1SrDX6QAhWtaWBuaCOHM8RtqUG/RfgOD04rqJ1x1Yzke7zOjRzsqAAodqzB/hi0ZahsbZL1fIM0Z7kr9uIGXSVZxXyx9y7UEnx2ZftkNcNCaKOO0wNJibkRGceDKWirDav1fNBJWtB9g4YyxK4WlBONVt/yJbg5h8kpqJNaqDJmmSwhrF@Z3ZsJXem1Cd3qOx55meAIsy/N2UR@buW//2d/yjeOnw/B/QfCPS48g7c/Em9tcP/TIETX4e2fh29FePspf3ubR47O7pbluQmZiAz86vCY@WTYQxb1jXEs99hwsShtZwTF2gdeXxHrEJxnK@JMhEepfwWch@ICtqPWgIoCpWd5DQX3OpbyeVSqcTZGo1Wh1phb9Wjr4zcj3PIPuk1@Y31jTc8DkbmrACHtP@rgMkSOUFVLIGqkK3tQedc02c7ODpN90@hZlY0yZ3l@2Xi7Kr8LCV0GWInr33UGcSBKFAPCqiKasmxkdBWjYv@Q1tMoKlouL0FQshRyAIiK3k6wgQO0OFewCqqHY42HpIhMgnEFyEGHtgRY/OCHAFEOEHHcuDF9upZHCwtxHXas3mvxYpDfINgpgpXkeZWs/padD8@dhjiggEGF@eWcKueA@w/nnFoQ1p7a7HZ5ZXqzO@aGPT11XFyAegDUMqWYL67m9Q011qZkgQroxRb0EVBCm4E2aFr2e3fg13b3D784Oj6d2fZNkOlpsDRLV3cy5zktW2@EjvRUrQ@Y@uwgf/ry2UHAyjhV0bwsQkSTs9NkzkttmtIFqb/hKzpn06aAmYT0wkMR0yxI7oDWL8xij0LzMcBdvpJsJlVFvbmtN3aq505qJvmP847CSGkrWLnAde7TQRhpNkfmHAbrVM/wnCZfC7Y4FOXooJdwQwN/j7wXb9wOT32Kdm8HK2Il2lcVbquStAVrZSHvWp4nRVuXOWEBvSBrAlJ1JDVK0JRm5tbj1DCRl9kDqsTej5BJR9w0QydSGA6Mxj3b5NA@CWhuwKFjFGDofhjrjc0uraehAeeEBvAgKkKLdssmo5PhBRt6wpBTq2/nzgJ6UHBEu7HFNuQu5K1nN8tGpT5m4XaQuzYla/6gZw8V3CE91tAwArlRVMyAvoNbjMfqznZD7OZmwabrDO3bPh4Bv47dAYuMUntW4DoBFYXtjQC5ieObL0Z9gGvT48TCXsICpSUHkYGP6YCIOu5UFnnQ@q11SF3rWuOW3YGeRlGzIJI@0/Vox7eBW5adNMhhzqrPccFhnDGftEs9xjGjbmi207LGCm4ILDWQO@Cfvn5zlVblmTpAW@XFxujW9J75QFgYQ9Fqo/3mUwJhezsUBMm2s72tdX0Jt@uAMgwpng69F@CEPlRp940BU0Z06IDPNEavyrniZP2hp7JcFfuza@awTIbG0vCgANCVEbRNLpt2dyp4Ro@Sr0A5o6/vtPDxwR6wuq5pDXBTIipbRjvaLqgbaIFSJRgbQZQSoYUOGP5KSBEonS2kiD@XKVmJ9v0C1NxgasidLjVA4AXlmlUfR5ssYy2Qc3V7uyRKIykOtxlUi505EgPQzhFzgW4K/BUbLoBrKMQAatezWjYIlKdfWo4D7VWBOtOH1smMEVQyT80GB@Rlo7OHKIUUJ/G52MEBhCbPJNpP3/Rc0GeW82UyyZRvod9/d44df1t0/ZP8f53X8uUbZblXmeRBGVOrynK3omdWVzKZZWdFWXZQHXn8GC05t8ug7VxoMDAaA1BuuaeWoT6DdlRZdsrLxo6y3KoUVygGvMLQ7AYifOvntZtl4za//Bi0iSz4eLx1Kss@HRdQ0DT9FujDFrKcz0KducF973TsHSa/bGcySIO2fIEEfJs/P81Qv3J@miejUVkouflOPxAjSV0lLImZ4/o4A4V3KZTo6yjRxeqbiwA4OpFodV7Yndr1l7hWkdG0quX78fqVDHm4YBECDYWTEDIKP68BGDhWgIn4mjVUFYTJb36T0jcYk59srCpu5sl6oZxJr@swPIRxXeopKKr5FdmTb873clfMyqXrbWNd@6ZxfHl8/EP1XGHbLJ3aPZL1Nfkt2y6yh302WXHBh/0un1RqJS@l8iv64818/t27d6CSw6de1aogPvhHrefSjbqyyVh1c3Mlu7G1kn2avogRpirFonrK8uzctu2B32rB1@3SGZVKin@ePKG0YNgJ/4z7ifSFI3hBEOGb@lQ4Yz3FzjcNYyWzVnzqlIG0bfysMh2c@LsFX52tr7N9/PzN//Y3P/@bn9Hfz@n7Vwa7ZB/gc9lm@E/uD62Y20B3s/0Bj1MA3btCcmGQTq@vpk/fptn/Z58lplefbP7nnx19kxqmqsX8Gw@ew9Q3qY2tFHeCA95Wg7erVDW1g2Abt6lJvlKpgHPzP/8vEL/6BeDBkMkO/FTXA1wbk1Q1V6EoH1PVDXDoxSKk@3/9@MdSqjpOfUjpup6a0N9FqqDjZ@ux/pgxcOTlzS3ZdZ8G9I5jn8Avr@vF86g8Y8WNRRt6dyEdKFfmppKg5A5rFRO1gRyfAoenmG4sPX23x5gFXS1@SqWnMwx/MfV@ouXgo4lmMMaX3DjIQmqrkr3gyYd1NRVzTGU4/GUi7@H7J8JJqeAUuFzdaDcSXD9P6VtrR0/HD/6wiOiAiamId2HibNov4Hr4woJGzz4FTkp9W6mcDPHvZRP/jk/x77cVc@wJfJbgj/7hE77i7xL5CG8Cmf0s/Q7NVUrVU/VG4wdd@vPw77mDf81v8O/FB/z7wRD/zkz8O/kB/i3KjJTa2dlJZTInoBqKOvuQz2v4atqFeAvqLqL7e/2wtaONo6cSS@UamdztbV17O86Uy@IflKZy@IYf7gKyGre53M7baiZTJ/LqVUHnTq5RBVo5yfTzdgcQZ3bqOzvaRbVazTXeVus7yUgi3tOnGWynTyFitVGvS6kbLIsK/qzgj@njb1GW8/SKnQX0ztvgYuSkh/BgdIowvkupdzvvlMyTzJNCr3BV0C/1y5fuUfR/dDSGAHtceO96hW6hq7dAIrKC9bowKUzGhb57pLfAacFfoQ9Ou9AeFzoFp@Do@mScQLX4v3/kDl8euYDNhZjDcWGIiAtteHaOjl4Cvjak/R7@7EKhMAYix4Ur@C/0UFDT2TL0fHuhnkt1Jr@zoPfX9LRWSGsb6bTdWN8YfHN@c1vc@EbOpi/O6@lGOZX3z8/zXDtixbUynSx0e3txsf9q7@Iij/VoZznzNJN7Cp9KNbMjHk9S1fKT81IOy4/XP@0ild95cl5dzaF7IwOFVAS/nXzmEz8RSnhWl84lGPC9eYPfN9dX19xFDnKdv3kThuJPHr3IRV7wAdD83PgJBwNN8x/ov3X0/6//l6@ZUm@ojCk3tzsKfVT8U9Wb25tb8VtVFUW8KDvwhx7wjlFubqvoJKAbcNUVtaHe3nI/@FXUHY6wimnsVClyBAgNNsVTPU@XQcOrLCtiMuf8fFwoqOUm@IT2Z@MjzQuoZVoxsdzEuRwYDegrKoGsr5XLa8K9uVUubwm3vrFRLq@EUAV4EU4AsnzDLGNFL6dUJIGPDRQ9X0STyzYMuPTVnZ2N9Wp1Yx1eNrbUnFLAIDraLX2eHgwG52mN7M8abVaqVGqeZ0zI5rQG471zaF5pXEVR2V7HYyy3ddfLba@qaVV9qwvURZWloOb57OY2RRxga@uq0pxYKlvbULYy2@KvsqSynXx1hYm/en01s7ayufK00Yi6dmyo5Rujot9WbowSDtNvy6Y4vqzndpjx@PHq9seP@lahfC5dXOzVzmoXeA60LKMUHDCGvtTmJZxXGnjpOhlV1rcbdeRU4zydLpWfct5urbNUuizgcmmQHmxrmxiagpGb3cZ1iGMUruJb0leKq0v59fFnG/sF0HQ/ruCnXq9vFbcyKyBdVra3G40G@X5cojj1/rjdoLNRKrm6vrHeyKEK8X7cXgFi9c3V1Io0oFUkmwXWwok4j7nt9hJ4dg2fNXHO1Ld6veDIuGvX67Wu7ZYF2I9f1Hb3z7LFHUBZPKjtZounr5@ldHxdj94peBXfT/Zre0evIcLxi/3a6f7nh1/tvz4Gfx86KmAWfPrHhjWyLqzr0ega3y8s@uzavvH@vTEYXEB9GYzb3//yJ9//8r/9/lc//f5XP/n@Vz//9Xc//wl8/wK@P@XPn/7b7XX8/fV3//x//P7PfgWefwXf/wDff//r7/7lj/mX3v8avv9HzO@vxTcGx7/ASsD2R7/@7md//uvv/ukv4PuvxPcX09/v/@Tf8f//U/yh81ff/8lf4494@clPAeHf/eUv8f9nf/l3/@GX@P8//eu/@8t/8Xd/9G/I8afc8X//q3/Lf//2937yt//4j//2975b8PuTO3@/e4D/d/8APg@n8yF4HpKvT/X57rei53fhRpQKVaqf/@H3//L3obb@CX/7J/AG/2HQH4QvYUiGhlS5TOT5B4x9zIPSUnj6MQQFlP8D@oI3@5jERr6FwPfX3/3xn6N3Avb34xgK@izsMgKHqf0BwP5ZSFgc9g@@/@WPv//z/@b7X/7p97/8IxRiubXtbC2b0@8ZlQDg@gPgEHDjIXAACB3Gzg5bYktSERxLO2gskPTMu3fA0iVwgfK7Iq2vwpukV8mtoxsiwlhihY9mMzhGh@9YWtuGNxy@Z6DbyPCgDAQ9y7BKpZKRxhUII1B4xThjVt3CcSfq6xXAi5F4nOzFFuiCbPyMsEDMSuaEXaxUxjxiBj2qhIEhQeh1IutFObNV2YMEK@M9hrgQeUZ6B893lepWZVxFdN8SCYAj8wySBKgKUjeufgvvFcIJ8NJ471sgZauSyVS3wKdCWaXUsheUpr5OmaO8ZxjlG/0ZQ@vVk6eMfSbrWzIfNwErmYDG30wE/YSsB08g/DyzIrJD/4GTvisYH8ppTPzhfjz8CXpTfAEAeHM5XCsD31wOqXkKwWOOKkPJwiPDMQDnMsLMEnpQz5qRMlS@GXqB9IGGh312qrEXRIfZWV5eBtdOVV6Vj0ABZ95lyR8aHpr0SUMqMXljW0ZvXI5kLR@Tir6ytwK/OvzvL9HyQc6OFWk5jd13mgVp5DKr7pqbIuqDrFFeVojyDMFJqcifq4U0LwP63BpTJYXOPVVpnGcNQGuRXvqdZ@6YKYWsLGf1jW1u3hTDwK/dUqnyrb62KcGT3kd45Ko4/BOKAa/h0LB1IUOrN7kdamngBBVjQ6pWxdwS06Xq6f4ZRDg7YnqxoDFQ7W7WNotr62vrxdWNjfXNor62sb22sb61ChJqo7BeLOrba2vbW9ubt0DQU2jn2dJKc32n@o9mPv/VP5r3me@LH6n6QzbW2PHxD3K3UnWcy@WLRHJFX98sTypACHlJVdKe@MhucpPzfYbFI503rY7t3OCSEiBNuslhVX0EHyY9ktgj8IIPYEbLOhMzmodHZTHvhQda87kvWV@HyqBK51AZODZpEP9IWHCPQdo81rlzfSNyFtApneGa/FeQAJSDw17gwrahy85cvoDqmWUugNjt8stbdj0X9M3fHuaZ4VzyoD0bj/4yh2HQcwMP9vD79rC7AOL1oI/bHCzvHwzDfr8JBKLxjwM8gx@v57rzADbZ6@MFuXwZ7uLBaTTaxgPgJ4efPz@LPc/2a7vPpQ327OjV3tRjXQCtsxf7B2fh6yYPDaKuhyi@3n/xYvpVPHDMsMTWN7NZEHzwg88sfeipLb8NQHRtcY9oaYWsnr2YWDe53G3TwmN@T/lBxkMQTOM2Vfye6@vpdMfqQ0cGTVWH2oyLKDtuD0ZJy4XdAhr88x9xlHNhFdcnbBnkntnbhlEg21mvbqTkdXmrUtzaKMC4rpKh05bbjsLUcmoDh3n17UZlzFbZVr0xSPnSS1yjtK3zJey2Lz2HsUkfT5rFDalDybNaME65dmh1fhNvdRgN2EJPeKAXOj270wUBeO2GAD7U56ZhMPh@6gdwWPHP8G6PIU@D/GZCerPg0nVoqQlNMKEphguFN7h6lHaOBNO91MX4JekMhTFd9cFwr2MTT8emLUTQy/PdfnSWtQWieVuScIrLbrOCpJHhqri9tb61vVrcym5tb62tw4BxPasXs/rm1uY21JWCvqVvbK1v69mtte3VNRDMELq@vSmlQHjZ7Xwe@h1dlulpOyaeQ7iDBzq6WrcqpaDcsSmxMV6OlDJCj9EWk1e3zgsMIsoSrqJcGVfk4houcV7VmS5LssFMljo42C0cHMjyM3xBK91uQZZb@LK@VShsPpNli0J2ofMoQqQuvu1voP4qyza@7NYODhDDe3wpbiEOWb7kIfylF7xsApiDL6urpADL8jchugIgdzlFWxRryF8KhWe7sjzi5OHGK4Cr8bc1InYfXzAAIx3wkF0Ik@XPg0gFYIN8wuFEUs@D/NZqsnzIX2o1RPEFZX6dZ@pLfKnRByJ58Ab1XpY74Oh4MJCX5SY4sfbLsgkuc2KAXx9ceKaBMzRkecLzgTmR5TFBG@alDHqd8Id0gJ7nz43usGV1@Gfi8acJQYcQZI9H@wfNzz9vdjpNb1Lb//yEgr744rnxfjLymp2miNi8gI@LsSDosj@Z/lgYdHFh9OYHfQlBzlTQxeTCIgovjG@AMvHpYEL9iy8w6AsImjenIxDCpw/ATfw868PzmdHkQcGHgug5bjblMlZZbDpthSqukaVHk6k3KBEV4wko6mtyCWWr2wb1arSl5tafjLbkjU25tAJP@Ym8Cs6xUkgXGJPT57Ksgkx8Im@uy6X0kye59GP9CZM3t@WSvLkpq@VbFMuKetNWxtlxpQAe@fwOtmNsefAEjUWoG2fWeKg9t3A9hZnLvUl8dnbeABzuL8RtWK9GffaMXZPowEXZwQLai8ozkBOFsoObTC18XR6nxlK1ZQwNGHg8uxmVSgL2ttyp1BHBR/zZyclvqm/kBounu75ZAKpeO2Zxc2enfv2xAWpXRS9PUtCTFLfKY3xursUVruWe4Q@X9c1iqT5aruf0xtJS4WNnR/5RlVDfQmZZ3DwHgqoMfgEruGiLhBP6DSqiLGSm4D0EfBmHkk5vFtNpNV0G4CXwFkymQgxKQQYBCKWwXQR9rexZwxFoB4Xy7UwyXFfc0KXUrdTC8wnXtqXUjXR7c7tTDTrfL9lkYmRywetjxjoZGDbkyWqP9v4lcuW06lNWq9Q6J7WyAK3tknIPBX3Od6Xk8kufOjeQ2am@5c9znBeCZCSink@f5Xcy1Xy1Wj2XZFlOyaFld2sdRgQ4bP42RdZatnvTHjm0wq/0EvlllLj@UG@o376yezdbq7kqrUpRoJbepjI7eZxz0qp5YpZ5RDOyUspxhRNtjEOotAooxesyDj8sNjjdfrv5duvty9dHr48O2NNCaau0xTlBU@RPs1k9raeBs0@hL7JP9qXU4KO7rn/rfFFOlQbp1bX0akLtOa@IPZkKVgSljpbw@mqjUYehRUOFt0ql@ERf38qslfRNNVXFvWHFzVSVHNAYcqupRoojWNtkKryQNbeop6p54a9v6mrKz/E3iLMOik1q6@W7jzAsFNek2UVy5fOCquXbnVv4r97WYeR0SwOoW/rHnzz83HIA@Efw8IU/ok8MLg4ThTe@ze3w/x362T3iNMsbwPHUu0oVCvbtxduLlJTaTlcz@TQrrgesE0MSVFJWHPqz/BX8ext5rIBetRK@wevOCluvwojdWsnn8@fqD4qgZWxvb2xtpKTfQPbvWJ8LoeGCtbYFgwCQUnNWrNU8@6WBq/mccNUaOF6OPuAFFU@Dm@0ChYShRoJLMlElifsJLSXmRRdCJv0mfh431aCvJKHLpptWWZvqEoqiIe0DYSt47Ahu@FWlG@kR4BqZQ9qPAz9lSXqEm7DwVQngsuyxP1Rx1X9BlR49EuLFH2r@8AKRYyThmdPL0q2E7DFaLZ/RFTE4icJ3CRu4o8Qd8AO6ehPGI/l0iwfXrsKD3mMEr7A2pwJys8IoRaIcM8eTf8TBmqM2knJw@GIf4sBQtk1rx0Rs2Wvi/UuUvaW2ykIpCTzAW0QqglMEjoCADjx556n2cSuySe2SZZiO4W1agwZQWaZniZIsa4uIdXxtQHRE3zZhpAKIeeoKzwFbuRDJijwIeigTwELMHUl6ut/D65hZUXp4yDXO7d0E@7gUDGU7rKjG9rIRLigMfmcqRTT7LXEZTCViM2HTG1ko2jLfsKaEcMInYtSttDLM9su8qAZl6UvFhM7e9ZTyt/3Hj823g3q/UVb7lSE@M5k@dECXis1BVoaVfgWqx6BuN8rDeiZjNyp99UsF3/HKJuythKbiqyJvkHOnArTgmj5fzX6oO7lvnUb2oO5kgORRduVHlQ9Zo1JAZSNrV/RsL/sN9No8H5DmsPIh45SNHfjiOszEXkLobDNGOeGFUS6VXuVD3Wig9tKDiJnMAWQG6PTrvUymoULiPQicjVjuPX5sZHrVcbmXy6kI9Xb1yUF9CI5GpoLvJcXYGT/5UB9B/JICzwok01OBeIgneH0b0g70lYHHvEwj0jmNpFyNgbx@pbLyoycrP1qpLC19qI9z/UaWs79UiGoDEj9G4sux3ZrKyo9UNsUSmqNV5M/s0mfaCm65szMZYHJ2EIvJKVz5EYQMMpmA6luUl2fxQR/WMLG9i2@mo@PzafqUBnk03OP3xaC4qPmmbQtwvtd@YOPOcTx6JksXLRkEgWHialkMPB8/eSIFSYsdRZAyChcYXho4xqYLBnGDJp1CwPgpO/fJ13liOJC54eiQLv2BcejqRqy5kmiiBud7Zh1BUAzcFG7LXGLxfWQgbEh6AAxJD4TLoRRBJgk5ISArIhBKKyggiIVyos1PiKJDclA@4S1ZYcsHEcLJgMY8hww7@75Csgnqkw0uZu9QeuCApiI9gkwgDZgHu8GqIMjY48dMvO5UmF7cxL4AwRDufUZHoBlKIfEHUAo4kMr3UEdRHlIiQNsjDMFNuomE1n63hMS@ewUiZN5n@fZ7jbbfKyPH58dVIN9UTgaWxaNH7zOVNUEQ/JPmDfEh7PY3KdHdl9ju0cvj12f7Jy9rp/ALY6ut@F1qwTWnM5ccDvDywqbt0F4/0zjRra@/MBlTcHyBZ@HjLcYt9sXrF6xYfLWXxRNqgfUpbuKGDrUUYrJ8uinE11yvk7@2L@188p53vHCWthXSrfK54NI1i7bC08XF4SEa0RkaPtq7oDMXx2omLqTqW74v7m7MBfdg05lmdJxIH0/FgFYo7nqkHRuJDdI4u5@ljTOe3bHpcuMuR5CIT5c2DXl0ah8S3tFI4zyo0dL2VqFQYoUsOvTAUQwcq4FjLXCsB46NwLEZOLYCx7Zw6AFmnWOGseDq6kbk3IycW5FzO3SuFSJnhGGtGDlXI@da5FyPnFFqa2FqG1uEl6UCblLTtTwM09e2gjAaQg/Jcx3Q6NOea0BocQYSoq/NeEJ6W0nPze2CSOgwf4RAxeJG9A7SJ4CtKJyqLKcjy1Pmb8IT@iqJD9uowu57Hkil/TFeSguVTi0x3AcvSbjoxOxZBigD1hC0lMoB1H9LLVEfNPQmpegQAMRQ0cN3iI5XekEcne5V5tVnTnBxXjDHVpyLjZ@FxELGxI5DEERyKkuJnpZjXEv4xbEuoYBFji6AKHIILIPk6QlBmmfeaG6Sq3cnmUA4N8kZojje9XmxkDcKIa8EUan/J2yVID2up1hU2qAGYEwodKoDUwWKpydVbvSS/OvvfvE/s19/97Nfse//7Ff/z7//79H97/Dnf8VjAoohwE9/xmilAPz8C0brAGg1QxSJ4FdL8ve/@CW8/nf/hn3/k5/xoD/@czm7FiKCEPSKYv78n@DP7@PP/y5n10PAn/8hB8QocvZWSqhWCkD99K8Yg9QQS4jsF3/BmJwBBUMRNa/O23gjdlIKRxCyoU6uxnQ4/8W7SIHHBTUjA17xpkdvGSwANYbcM/CgrqjtgTrDzXQopU3D7OLpA8LL9VH/MVGFcX2tA/XtugVKjzAvpCH3v8dKLJ1BGDST4GFRFS7DRf5FvuUoFGEzch6ow@v4BCq6qTWkBIa3EtRvGglMfA2HLTQi1XkdEfx9ZUE3EXQgclCz6OZJSaQVxEbbirjEm64iDYa6WGmxG@KHLdGckCS2x@uxBBPiZqrYIJVpHxgyRuemxKOSh9Uf4LkflYjfyFh8IS5kp9FFJSeazf7RwVSDwU8TVMzLuEQKE6owWb4HFjkt4FXUuFaT8JxeAVAvlFYbiRNY5gHLP/zhD2Up5lfAOuS1FMIQyxQXGWGQngwqxoKKsSC7LXCSrFkvFqdooI4D5WLy@CEeLSaiktGiyoUtJygHJAPGgniBryxn272R363MoiaJnBR2s8hjKPVGRbSTc4dkTpXJ6kwEwJmMU5kuy/moCzMwswU1PyZyO@GTKK3FmBJxYo2CuCdNcyksOX17XsklE7wDtd7IPDChYuF3TCj3wIQ21u9PaLpYMW4C/WL@3i92AjERSvgIGW/4qUQHhV3jL6DqReIIKfbIqagw5KmJIU/z2mXKnNvawT8fHEmfuKLdix1Uj4MYPFCHmweeDlwYcrioBQdDJcNhrwV4YtjBL8HtOK5n@fGjbcS9uE4aTxwy3Y4DvVoWj8a3Ly1xO7IljqtM9ithzya0UDx8GIY@iJozCjXPiwvbsYcXF6B89tpqxEB81UzckZ2WTIgIrlh8JVRtjwaKi1d8DNX7cZK@y6Od2ealcjQQgWlIpMZgQGdaPRh8sS5eJR3cC4xZ5JdLg0baHCp0DG/X7bsdy3HxsCWMPYX@MMKNBBmDAdGSZUaWmTGKxCBaMbOGKqJ@@clR2ZdFvEs9iF9MIkgwI8u8aR4jZ705yV0sTI5HC9I7/XR6T@P0nt5Nb9v2/OE0zeSJ1h58flrSq0qEAQAjMlbvJyMrzjacISdBSujto15EER5MYouWGbWQ0hqA1gS41ob6kQ3ffNp7LQj/ahH/7y7AIPr@Q4uPlNnTCcibPt06TkM0P5hQVgD8UFXDVYjx5MKqvffAtMRAh0Z4WSaT4HJwYz80zMHAcqJrnwPE99R5XAo0U@9pfVCFB86hybvKssvi4iLau2hZPWNitRQBmY3hDXJ8YhktklcPyzgKOhJ6MAYgQ2YhqydUMTqAhYBKC6qMkb1S1cXVioPYYe2hyTii8HAx/8hwNy2a0Qha4XMgrgcSNEWHhtIZr4PJYMIPberRaWqBHOX9Dy/JV644ru1OhgAf@HXmejZKVr1LfJ4oYZYe0COEsFoyy3T0QdBtuaCNz5Thp7Ho/pySlSGMVAlKOaGdLCpx@64Sj9WKoE5yreRhVfK@SvfgOherahxZJMJ2P60LmcG8a/R6pqnEMXKfO0vMdWZkAvphibnOgl7lYo5ADWOSpBvi1aUVrl@okg3OQ3hewfMreCJCGINe8AoV5A312sDkRSF9YxDTWoRP3URdNMZFNT6PGIOSAjcacm/DNM2FaZozaZqJNMMWkEwyBiSZiSRFKWDx3FUEPas9XCCdMQhH7vC4S2zDx3END@deb9J2umRnWfoqXQKBnLbSpX0FhHK6lS7tkcNPl07JcZkufQmOqG2lP6ZLQbNAAA9eyfEU/YUIx3czXdpV1FtpiCcmB@lq6VJYpgDzhL8SR265ebUpZv3d0KpqWVmuVGYZ1hgfHi5mq97I0rcA//xoVH6ENwQuVVhxhYBxAJLoNGI9Bk8Hug2t515bnjKv@ygFpilh34hsKBCeqcSMKlhLRiSP0ql0UhhxwjCUjI/wBAJRbpbmU8T0mZHZfeSI1KGGUiEn0yfuaaQPtBQKrwNw3IjTi@IH5ZVEwQvwYXRi5EV0zpATJEcU4WIAdQ5ZyNR36TsyhWU9dagzL/14Cc3aCLAQcwEILyVCG5PpoMOhbkqJDdxBspJQKM722fE4@BGNEmvvVDSSCqJlLggmb5EzFAzxxq/elZ1YPCQtIYIwsF5o8FYW9gskizEoknUxTZU3PiAhJnNadKqdhdV2TzgJjoubLPUVi7qhIC5PkiRXUkxCZA03QI@MIU89mpfBbdGfNnwNYo7x9g8FEcRihqlw@ep@gv7ucv09UKgDJkwlME@xnt@VzqrXd/ayU5T3omRnCxADs2xPnaschSlELIfRQUwzv6uuzaj4eMs9V/J5oiH2KW0/YFs4JriHb9NjC44LtQTvKul5iYbZy@JiRs1qJL0rLVBaNExJ4OEZDymNsnY3rTzj84oYQ7CPhscnF7CXLOB44SE@yoA3xXLeynEjFc1ThG2bziaLZi74rIOLq8TC88hjniDuaf1auEQLPI4uTvaOXr34Gjrdzc1NdXYqAlstxI36cenOaYJw2FLM4qmeuBOO1k50XW@4dO7Is0vKyAOUAYPmbXj1E21cFbIsJs@n2i7E47Axjgpcl1EzMBJSCVUdA7tsW/CVX5morBgCSaDeAr@zNFrDWSOsHTihc3FB3dfFBS7OubgQvRgWTTiN9JsUEyfaSankGibSs/yZA/Nw2D/q02akwOwmjsLjq0/weKrDYRA7jDVyhnawxAGtQrTTMZjBV1Z1tEkctkMfogOXYijFNRy4FtdVfFAshEZzJy2oFOkscfUG7zbxB65DZ3rTOamkrONNK35gcCWyR861QYs/eCp0@EWMIr4MK5gNcx1@7YjP4@IWSzIcB7zJMquj0TxPcRsGGpf2gB/1HC748FWKRATTyizgcbNn9YGkU6ixc2zIL22oNN0Du9OB6pMXt3/yZS1nBkTNue3cbnCEYYp9ZfTs8E4HsRKMrmQR1l9gp5I4g9JnxQ3QobazwNnoC4zFxTEMz5ks0NIsgoLvJjw2uXMrG4u7pEzU2eeqvqRcYIl@5P2Chzd8XhlOjL/0@Rg3RIspSmr1sXlKYK4jjq5L49l14fGHkjgHt0LTlBouURsockoOzkVEpzTwLBTXOZ2vnzB6ZnBgo4JHhZakRw5JIFwKxky@yAY0XQe1N5pnU8O1qQ77jK0WJbqfxiUrMycAcPApvgR2CIOomA@@zE9IGvmzlvwZzipKj1IoFHn1w/hB7UY33UEQVW@2JNDhelcxhcmbRfCyHnvB1sFvlIGs42hkAyicQ8mSImcAbUZWZY46jD8dXUyTPOIiehZTFmfqHglWA5bffPL6bcvzHAKTrlyoyHTru1h7XL5jNTAtB8Y1h4nFwEh0fHVnWyx64zclZuXXuGyrxBOhDkfDw3JR3penBX5OD9Z40gMXV7MV2ijcTvROsoeRQzKWbOcuAqgbooqOYorWjH3ml@ALNGQDlMAmWuagEG/Ue2kjjuDiazopq1GO9UOKHqcGCWz7II/awM@sTLdLPIaI1C9DJ6nO07UK5UR8IM4fOLT8W85pMkUVS5URUxIFL030DxfMSrRKPpB7dxz/b@T1rcLGNi26Zk52mO3XtxvZFbMiM2toG07fH3nXrcuO270CDYMN3jfH5uTDN4ytrzHcXlJ8zM8U0DcquKNDYZvwu8W2C7S3QxD4hM5HOJcZo025eBhCmrFwD1B5CbfkwyeLPyW5PFNL2Uo/qIV85XW/vtGoOJVCuV93GmUnk1GHmcowo2cU9Hisq2UQ1NxWUx82aCllfoW9DNY74uG4aJB12@zYdcyum/YZ3bccnwikfVRBA@obg3h7uoKhiuvFfdpYn4x@oiHOetFdhVMxbTeAG04GForRcKloDy@rx59Ho4218mw45vDRI1zXXBYKbTwDN9Jg1OzZJogn4ifqJbjGsVQSK/VNhvUWZBf62dyT0wIdmILB5SDUdAcTEdnmIBdBXnZiKKsKdn1q9iGQAVQT6uQFXmXgARgH4exNgDNATT2YyqlC9wvLCXsn3FyhlnHpOVsKwoJtGAiP9YY2Q1yAzkhbJ@CxwwQoLUxmqlgGTL51G1cikH5XTfOgR@9H/QGpBxqnV3AELw67GBi2F8bU/BFePagwHZlhB0RjCaDjFrfKXYE2Gi@aoCzQGkEz4pgfxHdMh20DwaaB19aCbMQZIcTXcinOI36lnQIdJrd2cTJEXMqGKooaGIfnoKUH6RIj40QZvKj7KcdC30Mo5nVBcB@C@8awuyC4i7hH/qJgD4LxorsFwTYE84Uq88NdCOeK2AKAIZreoLpeDN2LoWH3FL7KGtdn33KBrbBMJmBsWAUYLxheHsn4TKxXZ0u8dHhlS1QvaJ9UrTgAVmlFNB58j2oLheIBGgqvF7E0OU/YDbs3MWGxAhZfUEogdjF9dSWBn8UIgPYHopTNhgeJ89IOM5qoPxq/9QiCd0Dmf/x4F2WiIibrn94Iah8vITSOxnLIuRXh4VdnReXKI30QkebHEev549It0FyjfASNshiJEN62onbdtkG3hKgqajmRN45DVfYk8qn7DVYKpUfER94s7udjcab24DCVWmSWNSOn@XCuGljvIaYBPXIzEha4ecsoz7DTD6FzSegqQIfcnKpnZqLOiFb6qZl9WG5SQB81auJNmQtaE1TDqiBwDnkGL9e4TODIltMl7o93LdlJZPYCZHyT4wUgGO4ADdizBWI86BNtR@MLhUDOF4prWbL7c5DbiE2BsHoIn/4eGhcyTnTZI7x@IimS2BzWzICH@UZ@Vaeb3FT2uKSfn7k6X2mWfpJGGtlsfaJa9wR6yRIrsHA3TZnd3i@HfjvO3ETFl9B3fGWxrAgKPaiJD6mCtwsYfW8lS2ah2GAJjiMJJBnu6ZJoZ@j8Tima77gIfAJbGG/bCzUwpKqcDEeaOcIgABTleKys0LmqkegUW2IvhoFyk420MLz1idcKUNnLUlyc43DugDrvuG@4n4c4Eg/B5YWoYXoBZXY70G1BDQ7iaeYFFjNnMvIT2nTHdVtKoDAJhYEwBMumASjL9xiFahVXL6PkITmh9LKOWHod9Ltl8FkSXtSvlOlC7UA/QyJWOtRsythsYvqN7dOlZBSOvREkFUwJoS2JSx9WmvZH6FAFejQ3UiDxcaMYbScWcp564oR4kHcNB@12dLwXDa13ZPQPCwJhqjDQjjYdUxnczrEy8I3VYsvxTXzoYpdtDXXisNDFqB2G6SE1OzsyJhOdR/Gb1FJ@5Hv5pu3kLeeK4f3eUio0b5Xw4sfcFlpv8fpGIU3IWE4GIagmUFKYmuZY10p4HSTaHiS@UZAMSDoeGUHmLjS6tUDr58voB64/pt8JDBYK2mgwdClEJEQbCtlH@2O0yb1AU7tixCDI2SE8EYyCkz7cd8LtVjmdK0g63uqpxlDUMSYJXPlclrH8kFBh9qs3JF@zDLOLRGDd@8iHU1BcVJNvJT8oetwAh6zAGUVw9vjS3wHZ8TAJ0k78Cb1D9vFdRwf3IUsk1nsxTpHIXosheC0zVnI0y2H8HWAAZ/yj07O9/ZMTjVvjuP2mhFMP3MyM6zZoF6G431lYWXEKAfdw8kJ5hJlF3Dy9SoSc5C/xCJMVbMKmcI3s5LzCTaI8Bzmd3mayEcKrHJxYQnPQ4s1HXhbEUusB6FHIuyiaEouWC6IFwDFWPLqXG4Zp4urcl1bfBYp3rV4PiOa8eBSxA53IkSD9TJi@X8c0GyHxPDw3E55LhGs8nBMVQWlm14uASnEgOXUTwd0yOQLLzqRVYZDpw1e05UdzvRjd5btgfQ0GaXYEXA2LktfKMGAnEZCLhbydU/o8ZCkRJ6zgYXidh4v6XRQlH1KZgH2aTB@fkiggixbGinUkU7VUc@wev9c@CiEJy3CvC4@O5U3VjjdKYRAR4iQHYgKv6sZmW61EWDJ6IHGozcjVnaeyJkxST5RpMrjBe6ZhzWkjMS5Rmhli3Jh6EkiHgpdiKAgnVjQWtNxqEHkiIk9iaBFqKUhWCrZvJxs4ZG26iVfQhP4Rf4LGniQugEvND3zEKR/zzPOJsCSDSOguyfPZlJQmQ29kcU@RqTt6kSjtyTTG@ULilYsjULNLN7IHaVp8uq7tjpzWUign4oIikBQzfA9DBKcjAD2ovouKEANvpd/kV6TPjT5ohT1rzGqoUxt0cJKUmAvFi5x9PIcLj55k/mgw6Nlisx27ptk2caRQcR0nhiKMMaVBkw5x1Q6Hz6JLzF1CJI0dIeZrm1@YLAL8UafDb79leL0eiFa809oealLNmfCLeXFvWpHPSIortVEA92DYFyOClxxvPeFlx5oUnMDDs9rm7Vvc1IyzcnjrLnRpJUn6wcg2L3c/Z8VCYVMvrOoxlgWm6oK2ukb3@wYqUhBQLOiFwrq@Jkm77mDC15sopoq41nKIMMteYEf/FdRNvI3asaQa9BgE6OPl2ZZ3ZbU0STqxWmQDbo6II1iV6X5pJ9h8jz6gW@EhRHhDtJ/l10BDDcMn9s/8QAGTVjtnJZziHVhe3x7yiWD3ysaLq8Np7bbb67nXZIjGGWXOD4zUt4bAlBWVJUmiwwIELaS70B5@4IYhbuk1mu4VHe4h2AB6qo1nItH8rIQ7W@kS9Fhi/IrPGCWQntkz7D5WpzkE4NaXiAMBAZC11si07qRBIiI@kYbg@uGWa47wuAQjKJk8SD@X2go0d8uzQfpGDKZSoWgx2qGAz54fnrLTo4OzN7WTfQbu45Ojrw739vfYs6/Z2fN9tnt0/DWdzcqeH70A6XLKaq/2wPfV2cnhs9dnR@Ah104hpkwBUu3V12z/h8cn@6en7OiEHb48fnEI2AD9Se3V2eH@aZYdvtp98Ro668@zDDCwV0dn7MXhy8MzADs7ylKqQTQpiseODtjL/ZPd5/Bae3b44vDsa0rx4PDsFSZ2AKnV2HHt5Oxw9/WL2gk7fn1yfHS6zzBj0t7h6e6L2uHL/T0N0oc02f5X@6/O2Onz2osXUxk9evNq/wSJT@Ty2T5QWXv2Yp9SonzuHZ7s755hhiLXLjAPCHyRZafH@7uH6Nj/4T5kp3bydVYgPd3/wWsAgkC2V3tZ@xwyJyn3cAXKZff1yf5LJBo4cfr62enZ4dnrs332@dHRHvH6dP/kq8Pd/dMyk14cnRLDXp/uZxlezEFJAw7gFoSD@9nr00Pi2@GrM@gzXh@fHR69UqGQ3wBjgMoaRN0jBh@94rkFJh2dfI1YkQ9UAFn25vk@@J8gT4lbNeTCKXBt9ywOBgkCE8/i2WSv9j9/cfj5/qvdfQw@QjRvDk/3VSiww1MEAJyY7psaJPqaco3lBHRxJ1RWKai5WSpOdnjAantfHSLlAhpqwOmhqC3Ett3ngucanvc6d8rtzgm82Vk@YQq5@@Se3aO9fdD4@Kl8cuT/GjqdreTkXSIMOpowEF7FLCj1VRctqznqXNhO28WheRiNz2D3/U4WT4JXmYIXsdxxGYCYKKcIqdTFxVe1Cxjnnl5cqNmHxEyQcV8MsTX@LihV5LHnGi0a5idsS3FGVR@LA3iy/DSMuK3lcWh8UFk@37JENFxIgogDM5E4KQqQtVAy0goTw2GxJGmKOWkromPMpo1FwfSm68OP8zF64X1DzAOEM1@3kM/jGJbIwOPoWEg/JEIntYnj2mgdgN2mJDXfsi47SiGeHA75hYFKDeIQ7BCGgR1FvSd60@pMRc9NxydicQUQKSvBGT3B2Tn8XmR8Eyxjolw0j3KmcNMePdSAGkoIlEKVJ0XLi8TqE@Uxj46bvrmtUC2H57vQGW0vaz88fIODuUJxrTzl/zz0520LlwLigYPQ39UpXoMezxscABqYjcMvYIk94VOq@XwsDmhlpE@GwHiAUBeBru0W9KnYVXct6tbx2CJ@hkM8PnTGnj2OUw9i@POT2stnrw8OQHIitWtb65sbZUkcg@QNf5jlz68xHTqIFrkLWvS1DWoaBcVayS7oPQczJxjGjlzE0kNAPOk7KDTyxHuhw@3MXEfgh55xMxBm18djnxw8@UzGk5s8md98viQF9XVuyxQVQElkVcXc9I0xafgGqEpUB0y@dbk3oVIb4w/iDpt/0MTDDIkKJKqY1R8MJ1BzYXBBck8@CFaB0tiGlnghiCYH9XhgBGuQOGNQZtLSWFwiSW@ibsdKEfRaLGhsr1TsFBOIWJqmIjg5j87BhCSOXT9owdzTBp8fivoGzq/FiY0YhOdv1YanwMaDMGYuOFGR25xFwxCYG9UKFNHjx2FKOwwNqaogitv/k@f5xVsDkcIXNLApxMHKo5DPYQgZoZ@mVXbDayoetYJ4yqLGineoufOyI7CUg3NqxHtwrB/juKJT/sjrOkxDCkC@DkBCdibY9Dvxg/D/F@TJHPw7MOAE7BG3SA7bzsh6ICcJK@cVjF6JKfZ1sGIstkwt4mbc6@sIzW28YLphxsQyvDGfWAIWiNKZBB5f83NelTkMwEqOdo14@8VTFagRdw0YOT2ltvuIz/R7jtkfKMEpqUFXMYO3kSWdKxsskcMXlU/hF1gsuRd46N1T2nxLMgMHXCDFmhP2mS9zHBmdZA5mOr9CRo@wlVPVRDboQQuPqlNBNK2g8Y/FCqOol2kFobegii4@gTWcDsGDHhMCP5gBCQQIrX2KZ1iwDdKsIqFz843L78nKz0QvjjfxgAikfpmd0epp32jTmBm7IrHUGddUY5KI57OWOEizaQ2vsbvocey0xDvCxpTPaJU5JiJskaEaEQhfVQOuUyd7HVJPZkqsryH1r51LBy@5sLiJK4DQEsdyxvfFa@ylQSd09h6WbzlKPINsrSbTP3Ro2bvJ5yvRNEcjd0gFR/qf@RFHQOO8Ru0S@qGIS4Z5iZ5yUEft65w9hgellRM5Dw6ahDEDHSM8T@m/XTggwLoytQaWyedOaEQq8Y6s8lmgvqCLt93Q9TW6hJ25ApkC4sAHF8wKNQhJRr0JF2nOtjaiL9zrUJRStPi0BJrT9bXWNEZ9w2kbfbs3oVWn792uk/edkT/QBhM8bD1pDaRLPAAOaB9a7I3ttNxrnz2D5oCGpNNXr0@Pk4a/mOVrl1u@GPsC0mDPKGVpBn0bN7L4bnsIRWOV2URc7ORF5h6yEwpLC5m1JuiBu4U8qkCQbj/UjD9/9Zp9bjmWB/rgMa25ZC9s03JAfIAyRasw/S6XNAh@gKmfitTZAeouZNkpM8smo05o25NEAgJbFquWAk0RCPbEWddom59AVY/ZBLXZDEf5agVGpa47EJs10GiKyiY3cbZHvayEB2q/OTx7joNxPjAn2wx0a4GtD22JXHXqc2MtZMYznOEEmCJNG2@A7PtsNxqjvRqAUVrMThrU9fGqnBaa/Xo@ZBVv5RJSgHoQaKqWfYUn@JIZ7iFlROtshdks4ltZbHrNiotjhOhIlJ4UlV4WD3LXsmx9m51ZWHfZcc8wYYTFTkcYfXUV9MBnrj9E0Jc1xgpFXddz@iqaaF@f1jRqCPgNjnWVpMOXx0cnZ8BIcW5RUDHCPhOZTyep8tVYwI4cnqcKuX@HAjmAB4lZfEfMQxU8OFxBLvMZC7kkQ9mbBpp7IYd@Uh0mkyya5F2PTnPFzTpQhRLNEVL1r1H48qkRSimGPUvnyQY30VPXEtJJWywpwjukrQf1qofzoe8oMvmBALDG5AexPBoZtMRZRFAmfasfUm8Pg97d4ADS9EG0IcO4LRUqRzqbRi0JuKfG8bQsXCPh45FOff/K9EC2GFdQ5XAJS7BjCeoMySY1zI3RtHs2tAGgy@y62OFwcRUUBJkg4sfUSlTi4QGI2CERLXOOkILW1XL7ISinSpLCHXrCf@BPTJelOjDMxpGWP7CsFh1fNRrw85kwXINW3oOeg@/dK0UHN0mpAq2b9EDY4Dl5IPtGPdzQjxswm7zMpSA3UKuCPZ9nXRzWc0SQo9MhNVI8RleZM8LOMpznVanYDagQGFdFRizYfQkoBlmclAKqoLypQpCLqkuWrnqi8p7enIkR6YRIf5AMQFx8VtdKBgToMe/COQPAK2klJGBq32dADN@zxN0JG1jyBfOL605xT5vC8wiZm6ghMw9sPNec2wZc1nHxF4G1gGN8jtCiOcKZ3aR4K6QO@KYh9VlIgApPdYtBFufgzM3FuTofZ07gFJOVh84V7afDWFQteC74ER0uyEdkRJT9z91A9NKuv57LJ5jC3Hd6bhMP0wRJAanhY5KNCjbuTSOwBKPjoXxnZ/IQ0J0gS4J0sbcp0F3YDrQPq8p2AotF9dzhBSUCKrwt0fYxRn0XNSdy4o9oUeSUEyeKotYxdaQoksd9QXYjWlmgFD5yiUUtE1fixOFFysko/UQUfSqKIC4ZpZmIUpSi7eNTpYsxUPTjM5mzQC@hVUlUAqwSFlBB6htjProp0GZAMtPgOd6JjYvFhqggCFg3Wbi/EMEbUnRuRmLanqcRvNISPFrxLS/LdA5pIXkI1ThYukdigKAS4RM6m8VRRIZUwQZ6Cc/kUANiRL52KIoTk1RhhnmAlMi2h3u1lHgqaomlBgafNUQoHzu2eNJ14gHO0svwt8IUkUAuTiwHwrMOhCgExtN5GHUYyvJiCeRgQYp6ZnqLCTgoQYnLb1oyxrsBRUm0q0Byhzi5c0Z2Ayr05@goJYlvyvZBr@O@2KPERMMpKnx4trxQ8qwxDM9ojplQUP8TWqyFJz9oIpQegvh6lHIj6DWSuVgIPd2VzIOJ9SohF@4CDpgd8mkh8OLehliHNgSUdxw8xroXaCQWrAu64LTPWUZaij2kveiuaXMJlWRbTOjyuNk5AjhZ5AFx2alcSbHzZUQOp7sRKdFzJiqJEnvDu3PYZ/x0YY5IlRKxkP@LChyXO8Yb9kI4ncOJYl9UI0JcQbnfVS1C4KDc76oWHDhW7HdXi@CA6ZC1FH@6XiRKgrMAFyWKEQPZlOIyKAgYx6HGU1BE0KQRP2DG6ilzqI1JVWHrlGZUpZBF4jy5ZBr0GPOCEdePJasjMK8elkYjyi30ceal1QqPyRC5D4dIVTnZJfDSnD4dCjMdpEBl1FDxHpMwAkhsbgQTY@Y@X7tJxwyl@YCFxqB4lGqnm9zdm0Ab9CoFdVahDI5UiojfmUt8bvZoq2iIVZq9tCdcXSaoxgVPrtdCaFmaM@Mr3UNVJkZVMnexEkqyeAGm3IMw5R6AKR/DJBr2KvSX5Ex5eHiwdR@K8/NZHPR4CwMpgQMkbctGIzaOg6@NyX04l0DZStGaOoOvKgsjRHryfTieTOOgw9q74Wyc8OwaaHX7YHnu9FFpCzmbrCtzKAqpSs2SlUWySGrTeFfABaoSjW21y2bXDkcCqftLmp8pISLjUuJuOAmUSh51FCKL2r@@gH/ZWLEm2wMnPGGGAW1Z@sTmoCEjuIWJbxULI8QEWXIcKgKSjLg7dFr40Wh1@qQJPIV@YTT13pw85QafmNFJh6xxiZWoccEQLhJOQW8VyLd5w7N700/NTX/gDkDHac8lgOD7aMfnRqkpkR6pplND6wf1ZXP7s9l8xfW2qQPjHt7IH89kvQhZx43p0Kgd61r0/ndhFnkJSuC30OTrQR1ZQORnc4nEiXZDGLeYM@o3LU96SFPnMTR88DHS4porSakUq5kwZBYHF9G1UXSmsiWSRDUYK4LPRgOcr/H54k5s3Ggjs3gFnobF29cJWpMxCbLR9i3DEScZiQ6z4@H8RQibxTPVcXMXpWA7JjDat2Lmz3f8opCWJUJwRfIdbC3PL3us1XQ7PKciG6UkyOK6pjJJjmm57wIFJ9RqCKo0ragEdQcnQ1e4Zi70JVDM1fkmsIdoT3cpRFCJFyUpBrxTqO@uo6XFzBwNQlaGRfMAVs5Tt0Ir9wPUrclD1a3/ApycLlAp5hbag@hgS/cKtelBPt2SG5yW3Z9zdMtXZwcHiQNPmpNgVNC3vPVCoYCH4MxciYcTFDhLbLv5JHQebeL5wfUX3lfNPEZNXoI39w48pAFAERqnJrCe4NTECPqb2KlcaM9xcFfOe59D8hN4WoyWcdrh4vavzqjyEUpknlVi7zCDmL93LLhzGhRHPmQQWIL1ZhAb1dArOVgmB@xBjzaeqBMuSSNkNG4WuxZw4qNSvZEeiXshyc6Hd/ioN9E2RPm51eu5WfbG9XqtJZnvDk1GODiIRyhwEFxKyBuPT3dKZJl1Zfdi92ogSOwmc34xE166y62ftJfJswY4k6ZgP3ZidfbHA0Wuv5WhYkKWM5jNDJMbuL2nI0MXJdMU@v1o@TFmQPaDoPvGQDGJT9PA0AeKvVSRCyhaxZs3@epgtKfsQpZxMYeSAFH5uTCcZ/dDI1Pnk6u9d21HgaxjsITb5WjrNxUv5WQBeMhc@Xyst5GHBY5D0ITnJj4sxm0ZD5367T9o3UbLAW5uJBtvuCU2dt5YPB@BMR5bFrsattvQvLglvhocNRagI1GZ02mVArJGFKxnfTMCfUZJt31x7B0utTmdOGaCkHqxkWXicLzy75ZHKWiBovkBP3HZxJc5aNYHI7pcJZJnZIbDBRSzcgcjXGAESfrMrHxzrdRqNbY8yGRYrfYMHLkcqz2rsT30ePaM7cH7M3x/XCmur5f5yrk99QY8nwWet@wZ4KAuCC9y24NXCKP7mXAohUW8nK8sZ8vLF5WdatnP12vPGvl8B1x/@3s/@dt//Mf5mnj5Dl@e0Uv9bQikaVp@2bxZfnxbxvf6XiO93KwvDxrpThlrGYr7155v9IzYNjHN/Hu5TDfYOW@qDDRatVJJs/THj9x1PoycXuTEmw@i6EZv0DUoOiMM1Uq6ln78GFw7lfSP0iqe3CH8jdD/A/gzFWU5zRcTa2n6uHa6e3gYv1wovLS0jZomTrgbYnGa7fg2ZOpdKpg9z9WZprFGjr0LycMF3RccMEkiS@OKUU7Mt4LIIHe0@p5WqVLCfPkpLTDi6574arS@36HlRcECJQqjxWAY6bNWiS@dIxwZEHgIX@abUhXe3DD7QC6udav8v@1dbW/bRhL@bP2KNYnEEitFkpM6ThOrSO96QA64K9A74D5IgSXTlCtAkViRTiyk@u8388zsCykmtoNcLy3yITElcd9mZ2eemZ2d7Y2HJ9@@7sVxjJYRnXueQsyhtdzfb5wGwbKIdJOMejktGRo718ZdHhuqkIkRxw9S6sfDVPM4rHChJA8Y@QqP4qMgNYahLmVyFeGBu7/XAG3oyTLWsOgdKfNrHLdmbLC9a@AedcBdm27eG1zpG8lNtdvgBsHg9mDOeFK/Wt4l6PSXy@NueVthWsvEUK9QiEfWPTjoTMdoPxPc2GeqqV7xY57YnSU9cb9ebq@WfOMmDk0U70g6EeU7OlnLlc2KyC1IyYtszhufsqJlwvyhPQDDjM/CrlLeXeAkpEvOvCuAz961TAiS1gMjHM3DMecz3@3lSo4KrOf0SAqfEyLKndJgw2@Q3EkYijfVkCJGyls5kOSEXXN5k6lKn32YLdiDg7w1QONgP@Ay72hJbOgpp@VjjugbvrY3AHR0JUVYKy5kh1DlGzZB2SlCROE3HyFhLYmGrZkuV9Omu6YRpYgmpZljiUQmieWaWejGK5qTQ79RR0bD6W1Xs1LJm6@LYqGBKjpNiMKRU8IbqnVy1JLGlFvC27iT3K2ocHyWlbIb4nP2g0nOEWqdBqlcUHmRgzc58lDi4uJKPC6uZGeRe5GVi1SOSknrh1YW50gHwt9K3pQPNkTGg4SD2glGCxOjp1A1EhRT7esBnfhUMq//Xxz0noFmNsRI@muztuRjxxxudiaeSL5GxwmooEoU7SOcU0rBgwpjLrOrRVkp05VD13q@VEaxs6TnRT5FxGNA3RplOTbIXoftRMJU6W2DsFnw2t9I0J5KdHUz79nBsFaTWCxXUoaExBmn@/zh5JHtTthrWsFEPl6@3eoMQbmyrlsUwscyJ55VjZ@Fj7aAyrWLIi8SnORHBSot6jTpjflS4Bo1SJzWloGXwoNK9QEDM3OHmhwyqkZemS6BBHvC2/KL7emu4ZL7/2W7lam82HCqWVp89BbzAeloH0x@QW@sUo9uXJWNK/BdZoE6i98Fzi9trpeE/CVIXTVKeI@8b9T1o9aUHbrOcA9IKbcJy8ZH4VzWitrx@tKvq6V7R5K74b3N4NAOkE7e0cQO@uuBKHPSprZeSc3QHtiPO5tDQlMwuMh0OztKcqjX2ZzJw7HuLM395OyaWMPa8FbK2zErsuDQmLBy1IXcQ/peGO/fQKQdXDgvr8v1q/LzY3r47tCbxdx9ibvqCRfMCAYrRJh1@vpEj2Pce/2ZzAKWAwsSBHJSZVZk9NxqCfJQCzP6R3H1w/qmPehOoknUHZ4860Swkx0Oi9OCLKM4zTiiesNWQqa2J2lijZB7m4kI31wsLi8JceiNC1RUW3M/nWu1Y/aQv3firuhB1UYQ4lkUyPKiR5OIL5TWeM43s6s3Mzz@c/3vzWz7ipQQPv60kvn8F9f3MykjvnkVv/wsa/TlJUGNaMd2sueJOw0RLvMZIZ@0BDQoM0mV4OBCAwGyPQJIm278RXWwARnC8YvvwqFn6E2a1KkglEJiw6eSE3AKE4CPJ5Cddi7fEW@qCVMgn5084icxCOoAkn@wJ3mCb6WEQP2lGXGZSko/n1ENjNdGa1Kqa5bEoANrcn18KGs5@Th1vS@matiU6S/nb66X5UJHtjcsOy4u1DVCimu@lkSHyVkEORve4owPQL3Aj0ivbDE6uwzrtAvGwfWOF7RKvS0DQeWpoEaYrSWwHy25MX64HT1oUFNFMrgfPwF/DHbPPzI3gu5H1tTgBOucxC2YDoyXaR6YG5Jx0OlZ40Z9WDE@uB9EFO5GkrNMFtG8C@eYZ5hTwEOYuMn9PWz2P7KRK98wyc49laxdqmHUIsO8rY/zw10z6GG3ILRqiVNQuFi/sdGWak4ExmtwNzStID5B/v82WG@x3CroLyCVPZ8ZYpfDykKrgEN7MC4gpwMx0MzhLGCsIRgJkQRETq4Z0ITOUZC0knV9g9gQo4TelD7XQbZFTG6kDeKNqthTnl0HI/Z@6lj05hAQXiWeurRCVbWbV2y6GcxePa/BbF@rmDKE7MYrUI9ZG4xwxwa3EirbJ9Tw0wgl/Wqik/zy2chUJUCVSrtWq4l9nejQA6PhWne5AvbkEgh36IBwrY4GoIt9zaBj9epoAi2yf2bBcGJeXpFYrGJhiRqY@e/E6hEDsqjlhnKOODlSc73JviNETOiqRf8I8rKUwvm4igeEIGu/5V5CJgimBujtvBGam8z0405Ld2b7EkrUHj4ddtDIHVpqVe7NuDe8FzHIWzHzvTQXrFAAORJzrqlCbtd@0HUfcEtXxtfokiaJ7J3SIp6TPOcju7d5qfuxvWHLUPWmYz7RQQ1fybHoIPbz9OPWAXVBkAYHbFFjKP2NOniLjIaR2yMz4s71iT/EPrSO7i/J/21pXCAlv@MABxAGFh0wPuNadYIVISCUEAv06EFxRKR2B@YbW/FQDXARpK1wstXgQ1XVjQ4hNyvQ0oX1KQJqB17FRq@p9RCZuLGYacv53tkSW0dZyo5w56UqOoE/WN0O/SObLZq7JSlRXJUVcRUO5@FDo32Dy7qGMRoN/QqhpB8VYkxWIpzrrEtCiL8E4VWl0DJxqC9v9D/IC/qGX50Pm4EIi1ePQ7yHpu/pfr1ylG@mDop@jD48oKt1LZUAaCL319kkj743rfsStE7PW5gUDr0/DpfeaybuyqouUXozL4oufjoUXRzqnm3RZ28Dax/Jxy8ZfZBCxusfk4Rplg5E/8JNQf8Jg/K9XbPSpQsjaV@UEjna8UEeRfmoKKG@nvvtR7bjRCfNLi9JHV/zafxtSVXwQXzcVBfQWQoVMCnupzCtkS7NqygkE5O7UrfMtLS3ywwMs8D8tfnHQKm5Jmw6oOoQXoScLbx1tU4lAxgHAbJzAHGlsGuHYhaxQSQFx/xRE6kczCUf@VxXsozAJOfarI5B@4NBCMb6YTMr7wSx/JacnG43K84Gy3cN1PiweNTiOzfvC8nugsuSO@OyOIFPO/HwLIlzwhaPP7GO3xeneQct1RO5nke8UOHAh8lBJKYJWm67oTNfpVa45fbpsO8rfPlSFUPyxcOXxJE/rYKYxIOYtBHE@Be0VMqON5Rz70M80LJdwUJOFPZIe@tqe7RubHvrxvaKjDMMG/@eFl6jWf66odny3VpLOEbVBuF/bGyIZa2s6Wmka3tq2vsLWubbq@HHX9Xwn1sN9x0t@FqBWzRNMPVf5/7PMPecqH55OjgdnH@2fV/3XRQyVlTbbzUmOjTD0fdPJzd/HUxunj356de4jEfH/f9s6G8Z/xqfnMbySA/06bH99DYexS/4tZNdvO2fnZ3Ro9by8m9Uy@jvrk5@a/uC/ht9a@s92caj3hmK/xaPTuhheHxMPZnc/PhscnM64H/R8y8JfoS7Kw58fKjWHNkrVSEU9souZ7ivC1/lXwLt8IpZwJrjVQcpa36qtIcOc/DMzfHpQLEKMZBk2XvLGQgX89KdqVL8iDxfJbIVyokLm2VPY/WkEK0A10SH/qAJaHuFXj6zn03qxyjBd9pMHzw64a3rqSb7cx1w6f0AMyWUm8yLNhrmRMb8dzT4PnLp/76LNDtgFEb8696masVT1Yr/BQ)

### Explanation

Makefile supports line comment continuation with `\`, but not `\\` (like Tcl, unlike gnuplot). 
Retina does not accept single trailing `\` on odd lines, so before make code every line that is not started with `#` should be odd and preceded with 
`# ... \` line. With this file structure makefile, gnuplot and Tcl end up in one place.

Starting make code: `x:;@echo 185`.

To polyglot gnuplot and make single-quoted string is used. From [gnuplot docs](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.2/Gnuplot_5.2.pdf): 
"In single-quoted strings, backslashes are just ordinary characters. To get a single-quote (ascii 39) in a single-quoted string, it must be doubled."
Also I found out that `pr` can be used instead of `print` in gnuplot. So gnuplot code `set pr'...';set pr'-';pr 89;exit` plus make code
`x y:;@echo 185` gives (space after `185` is important):

```
set pr'\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
```

Add Tcl:

```
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
```

The rest of polyglot is hidden from make with `ifdef x ... endif`.

To simplify comment ending at lines 231-233 I used Ruby `__END__` instead of `=begin ... =end`.

Test driver: `make -f polyglot.poly` does not work because for some reason make tries to compile `polyglot.poly.c` created by `/opt/brainfuck/*` transpilers, so
`make -f polyglot.mk` is used instead.

#### Alphuck

[Alphuck interpreter](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc) has a bug in `TrivialBrainfuckSubstitution.cxx` line 108:  `'.'` should be `','`.
Further assuming that polyglot works with fixed interpreter. brainfuck.exe from the repo does not work, interpreter should be built from sources.
Command line: `bfc.exe -nobanner -l alphuck polyglot.poly`. Polyglot file must have some extension, otherwise it is not recognised as code.

Batch file to run alphuck:

```
@echo off
copy %1 tmp.x > nul
bfc.exe -nobanner -l alphuck tmp.x
tmp.exe < nul
del tmp.x tmp.exe
```

### Refactorings

This answer has 4 sets of changes:

- clean-up at the end of longest line
- 1L_AOI/Wierd/LNUSP polyglot with cockfuck, Fission, Cardinal and Morse
- Archway/Archway2/PATH/YABALL polyglot
- moved Minkolang, Rails, rk-lang and CSL into 2L

Other changes:

Replaced Thutu `__DATA__` with `__END__`. Didn't replace Perl 5 `__DATA__` to prevent `__END__` becoming Incident token.

Nhohnhehr is back out of LNUSP, reduced one size. Additional column of spaces to the left is for 1L_AOI, spaces to the right are for Retina.

#### 1L_AOI/Wierd/LNUSP

```html
<!-- tabs code from https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl -->

<style>
p {background-color:lightblue;display:inline}
y {background-color:yellow}
c {background-color:cyan}
m {background-color:rgb(255,123,255)}
t {background-color:lightgreen}
._ {position:relative} /* make '_' visible */

/* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-superscripts-and-subscripts-from-affecting-line-height/ */
sup {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}
</style>


<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">1L_AOI</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">+Wierd</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">+LNUSP</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">+Fission+Cardinal+Morse</label>

  <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">+cockfuck</label>

  <input id="tab6" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab6">final&#x200A;<sup>*</sup></label>

  <section id="_1L_AOI">
<pre>


 +    +





 +         +
         +   +   +  +    +    +
                          +++  +
 +  +  +       +      + 
   +            +   +         +
   +     +          +  +    +
 +            +       + + +
   +    +   + +      +  
   +    ++    +     +    +     +
   +        + +       +
   +     +   ++       +
   +       +  +       +
         +    +       +

  +   ++     ++ ++     +
         +     +
</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="Wierd">
<pre>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>+    +  
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>+  <p>x</p>     <p>x+x</p>   <p>x</p>  <p>x</p>
<p>x</p>  <p>xx</p>  <p>xx+xxx+</p>  <p>x+x</p> <p>+</p> <p>x</p>  <p>+</p>    +
<p>x</p>  <p>xx</p> <p>x</p>  <p>x</p>     <p>x</p> <p>x</p>    <p>xxx</p> <p>+</p>++  +
<p>x</p>+  <p>+x</p> + <p>x</p>     <p>+</p> <p>x</p>   <p>x</p>+<p>x</p>
<p>x</p>  <p>+</p>     <p>x</p>    <p>x</p> +<p>x</p>  <p>+</p>  <p>x</p> <p>x</p>    +
 <p>x</p> <p>+</p>     <p>+</p>   <p>x</p>   <p>x</p>  <p>+</p>  <p>+</p> <p>xxx+</p>
 <p>+</p> <p>x</p>     <p>x</p>   <p>x</p>+  <p>x</p>  <p>x</p> +<p>x</p><p>+</p> +
<p>x</p>  <p>+</p>    +<p>x</p>  <p>+</p> +  <p>x</p> <p>x</p> + <p>x</p>
<p>x</p>  +<p>x</p>   +<p>+</p>  <p>x</p> +    <p>x</p>+    +     +
<p>x</p>  + <p>x</p>   <p>x</p>  <p>+</p> +  <p>xx</p>   +
<p>x</p>  + <p>x</p>   <p>+</p> <p>x</p> ++  <p>xx</p>   +
<p>x</p>  +  <p>x</p>    <p>+</p>  +  <p>x</p>    +
<p>x</p>     <p>x</p>  <p>+x</p>   +       +
<p>x</p>      <p>x</p> <p>xx</p>
<p>x</p> +   +<p>+</p> <p>xx</p>  ++ ++     +
 <p>xxxxxx</p>  <p>+</p>     +
</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="LNUSP">
<pre>
<y>1</y>     <y>!</y> <y>!</y>
<y>2</y>   <y>!</y>    <y>!</y>
<y>1</y>+    +<y>!!</y>
<y>1</y>   <y>*</y>
<y>53</y>  <y>+</y>
<y>1</y>   <y>*</y>
<y>51</y>  <y>+</y>
x
<y>1</y>+  <y>*</y>     x+x   x  x
<y>49</y> x<y>+</y>  xx+xxx+  x+x + x  +    +
x  xx x  x     x x    xxx +++  +
x+  +x + x     + x   x+x
x  +     x    x +x  +  x x    +
 x +     +   x   x  +  + xxx+
 + x     x   x+  x  x +x+ +
x  +    +x  + +  x x + x
x  +x   ++  x +    x+    +     +
<y>15</y> + x   x  + +  xx   +  <y>?</y>   <y>?@</y>             <y>!</y>
<y>1</y>  + x   + x ++  xx   + <y>?@</y>    <y>?</y>
<y>1</y>  +<y>*</y> x    +  +  x    +   <y>+</y>   <y>*</y>
<y>1</y>   <y>!</y> x  +x   +       + <y>?</y>  <y>!</y>  <y>?</y>
<y>1</y>    <y>!</y> x xx              <y>?</y> <y>@</y> <y>?</y>
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 xxxxxx  +     +
</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="FissionCardinalMorse">
<pre>
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1   *
53  +
1   *
51  +
x
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x  +    +
x  xx x  x     x x    xxx +++  +
x+  +x + x     + x   x+x
x  +<y class=_>R _*</y> x    x +x  +  x x    +
 x +<y>R"12"</y>+   x   x  +  + xxx+
 + x     x   x+  x  x +x+ +
x  +    +x  + +  x x + x
x  +x   ++  x +    x+    +     +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?<c>@  %"18"</c>      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1  +* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx <m>--... ...--</m>  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 xxxxxx  +     +
</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="cockfuck">
<pre>
1<t><<<<</t> ! !
2<t><<<</t>!<t><</t>   !
1+<t>`</t><y>`</y>  +!!
1<y>=</y>  *
53  +
1<y>></y>  *
51  +
x
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x <y>B</y>+ <y>===</y>+
x<y>=</y> xx x  x<y>===</y>  x x <y>>8</y> xxx +++<y>=</y> +
x+  +x + x<y>,<t class=_>_</t>8=></y>+ x<y>B</y>  x+x
x<y>==</y>+R _*<y>=</y>x<y>==</y>  x +x<y>==</y>+<y>></y> x x    +
 x +R"12"+<y>8=D</y>x <y>B=</y>x<y>D</y> +  + xxx+
<t>`</t>+ x<y>`=>8=</y>x<y>></y>  x+<y>~</y> x  x +x+<y>B</y>+
x  +<y>====</y>+x<y>>~</y>+<y>B</y>+<y>=</y> x x + x
x<y>D~</y>+x <y>8=</y>++<y>>8</y>x +=   x+    +<y>,<t>_</t></y>   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1  +* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 xxxxxx  +     +
</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="final">
<pre>
1<<<< ! !
2<<&lt;!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
<y>#</y>
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"<y>_</y>     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 <y>\</y>+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 <y>+</y>xxxxx  +     +
</pre>
<br><sup>*</sup>&#x200A;with changes for SILOS (<code>#</code>), DOBELA (<code>_</code>), Retina (<code>\</code>) and 2L (<code>+</code>)
  </section>
    
</main>


<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 830px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #_1L_AOI,
#tab2:checked ~ #Wierd,
#tab3:checked ~ #LNUSP,
#tab4:checked ~ #FissionCardinalMorse,
#tab5:checked ~ #cockfuck,
#tab6:checked ~ #final {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

#### Archways/PATH/YABALL

```html
<!-- tabs code from https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl -->

<style>
r {font-weight:bold;color:red}
b {font-weight:bold;color:blue}
g {font-weight:bold;color:green}
y {background-color:lightblue}

/* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-superscripts-and-subscripts-from-affecting-line-height/ */
sup {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}
</style>


<main>
  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Archway (74)</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Archway2 (98)</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">PATH (133)</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">YABALL<sup>*</sup> (132)</label>
    
  <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">ADJUST<sup> *</sup> (113)</label>
    
  <section id="Archway">
<pre>
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#&lt;!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -<y><b>/</b>!<r>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</r><g><></g>^<r>+++++<</r><b>\</b></y>>+++.-.
endif    <y> </y>                                                           <y> </y>
#<<<#<y><b>/</b><r><+></r><b>/</b></y>>>>\                                                       <y> </y>
"""#"<y>;</y>  print(85)                                                    <y> </y>
#<   <y>~</y>#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+&lt;<y><b>/</b><r>.---.></r><b>/</b></y>
#endc<y>O</y>mment                                                   <y> </y>
#nocO<y>m</y>ment outtext("155")                                     <y> </y>
#ce p<y>S</y>9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE         <y> </y>
#p|o5<y>1</y>~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[<y>1</y>]==2?158+4:17)#>say ...
#8M`|<y> </y> &lt;esc>dggi2&lt;esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}&lt;/<<y><</y>}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<...
<y>#9'<r>>+<r><b>/</b></y>' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n<y>*</y>n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*//...

</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="Archway2">
<pre>
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#&lt;!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   <b>/</b>
 \? <y>    <r>-</r><g>/</g>!<r>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</r><g><></g>^<r>+++++</r><g><\></g><r>+++.-.</r>         </y>
endi<y>f</y>
#<<<<y>#</y>/<+>/>>>\
"""#<y>"</y>;  print(85)
#<  <y> </y>~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+&lt;/.---.>/
#end<y>c</y>Omment
#noc<y>O</y>mment outtext("155")
#ce <y>p</y>S9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o<y>5</y>1~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say ...
#8M`<y>|</y>  &lt;esc>dggi2&lt;esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}&lt;/<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<...
<y>#9'<r>>+<r></y><b>/</b>' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*//...

</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="PATH">
<pre>
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 <y><b>/</b><r>.</r>_<r>++..</r>_<b>#</b></y>&lt;!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#<y> </y>  /
 <y><b>\</b>?     <r>-</r><g>/!</g><r>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</r><b><</b></y>>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif                                                       <y> </y>
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\                                              <y> </y>
"""#";  print(85)                                           <y> </y>
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#<y><r>+</r></y>&lt;/.---.>/
#endcOmment                                                 <y> </y>
#nocOmment outtext("155")                                   <y> </y>
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE       <y> </y>
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]<y>)</y>[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say ...
#8M`|  &lt;esc>dggi2&lt;esc>//       <y><b>$</b><g>}<}}<}>}</g>[<g><< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}&lt;</g><b>/</b></y><<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<...
#9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*//...

</pre>
  </section>

  <section id="YABALL">
<pre>
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#&lt;<b>!</b><y><r>.</r>_<r>++.-.></r><b>@</b></y> A=AgRA;       AC
#   /                                                         <y>                        </y>
<y> \<b>?</b></y>     -/<b>!</b><y><r>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</r><g><></g><b>^</b></y>+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+&lt;/.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS<g>9</g>^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say ...
#8M`|  &lt;esc>dggi2&lt;esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}&lt;/<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<...
#<b>9</b>'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*//...

</pre>
<sup>*</sup>only normal mode path is shown
  </section>

  <section id="ADJUST">
<pre>
}{}<>        <y><b>K</b></y> <y><r>yya+-</r></y>        <y><b>&</b></y>  <y><r>g+$</r></y>
 /._++.._#&lt;!<y><g>.</g></y>_++.-.>@ <y><r>A=A</r><b>gRA;</b></y>       <y><r>A</r><b>C</b></y>
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~<y><b>#</b></y>class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+&lt;/.---.>/
#endc<y><g>O</g></y>mment
#noc<y><g>O</g></y>mment outtext("155")
#ce<y> </y>pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say ...
#<y><g>8</g></y>M`|  &lt;esc>dggi2&lt;esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}&lt;/<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<...
<y><g>#</g></y>9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*//...

</pre>
<sup>*</sup>ADJUST code unchanged
  </section>
    
</main>


<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 830px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #Archway,
#tab2:checked ~ #Archway2,
#tab3:checked ~ #PATH,
#tab4:checked ~ #YABALL,
#tab5:checked ~ #ADJUST {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Press "Run code snippet", then "Full page".

Answer (score 11):

## 187. GolfScript, 9346 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bcyPNkhj2TMj/wC81DX4DgLg2QIAAQWAGvA05wyE5vAxnPpIfpgE0gCYb3T3dDRIYDr84sh1rrVYP0mqtWGktnbNrO7wPivCGww9WaCMcYb0qNvQbvn1ybDji/IPjzKzqCy7kzHznHEmOEEig65KVVZWVlZWVdemW4vR/85softihqY97uukyV3Vc1rG1G9XOsPUxe65oTjFfiEQQqmH3hgPVcJ3VSJTJjGlGW@uAn7nmtWpon1QbwvOMWbbZs5UBc/uKy1SnrViqw8yhaw1dZnbnJyswtjUwr7Q0phxoRg/AXNW2bNWl@GXGTg1dGbQ6ylRMcSpDy4Z4h22q@ufBZ5e1zcFAMToOQJYYe23ajorwbdVxTEy@wthoS21PIS0DqGJr5l5j/8VUVIWxF1BExdLVEVNajmsrbVczDaRJjh3vnx4fTqWQZfb2ZHt7OjTPXqVNg20P29fTUQV2ajuKrkzjX2aNoWvuutPhRdboqYbC8plKJj8dWWLrtjKTZIXZqtLparqagQZhadZXdUu1GYawrmmzXSiSXs6Vc81GkDLTxrTlIHIabYXphYI7VZ98Dghv2n3VgBLmpiNlP3IqIu9HdDTKQLHHLO70TRv4yGZDR@2wW9PuAHMZ@jiRgvRs9Im1FEctLSOCgo/g2jBvDWAi14SmbY1dlRmmkabECLjM5L3mNGPlixjaONidDi@x/N502AowWvu6O9uW@TI7Mq3xdGiFvdb25rFzIcc7wobZgdaYipPZoQJBlE2Y8NQ9D22zM2xj13H7KqTE7oat6UTa0Px1ZolOnkEHi1L7czBAfWwO1HBuDjNUIK9jqW2tq7U5W6gjVzUcyNDJMA2KcKvpOuuoOiQIsLdTzDGxcYKglq70M@1MBNkKc2GDa51prG1ZjEcxXYMibefKTMW6s08Qr/cdNrIGzNEGEO22zW5XVdkn1epD8kjHjDD4tK2pavm@RRVgDNUjjWpBd0bSmNj7gU4ehW5txQK@dwQNXG0AwkpzYw5TFUdDcQhJHNXoEFUtX1CaTJlgWHajQXeFqg9twu2oNnUYwgudy1YBpeKLqvitrbku8TxrsENVsdmJraqJSaE5kSVkZmIOLlYkQ426thbbOtiOQePyFBnFgsa0CydvXkYUlqmxxWYVvjVJqka29jfZ3eIFurmMBAaw7LiSYLUfmZO9uFDhO5Jb2Z59HwGsEaCKzrKm5WaVtAUFTLtQwKyCTnSlb/IZSw9lzNam2iLEchyqA60BooO9TVHN2kPbxnEgIKpyDZXWTaMH9ITK2kMD6WGwUg6aoG2CGE8x9QaoBnKT2gh6NVL4pK9BoznYJKFuwUczIiiMZ8DGgqJevo6pDwkOUjou8jJQBZIixt0ue8u6iqZjEohHVLzUtuoMdRfTDI0OtjyMVmonw7xitKHjAtDAvIHsFEBKAcD6g1C/pEIBMDSESVXFqJ/@8Z91ej3A02i3QTIJdn3LOmabxl2FCguDGUOGBXGoU7EALoW58@SQwY2iax3FxeyNsciCCkG53ppDvcNMyNC@1aCX9pUb6NnQudquypmcD9UpNlCuuTTROOdCxQdKCxqWMqC8qdpp9nwDWqmtRqLEM@nB0O2WWdraYjEn@0P82Wr82ZMLFQqXyCSWFrPZXhUYLrNEQeCLPcY5bxsTA4zjKo6pdSLW2O2bRp6l20xq10xLNeKxCRyxVMxuxRIZlHLxRFWrtTNdzejEY2vAi3XIOJaotmvtc231sjqVPJwloLlFNNhd1Xg7IUVA5FCnuMkOQBZnQLS/TQtXKM50mkhyjM6EgpEw02E3PCBKqgrypYkMAnIo4@iqasVzGTmBYgLh5tYbI@bVdAqHqPCqdpmMRWPJcNUJA9R0oqLYWU80E8WWbvVxyAGiGI4FI4GNvNuGcRYlo6O5oC@mWIv4mkYRkCwkE2/VmK3igOzzEXVJ3uUwfRoFpcAQdKHJnqx2Qh0ZhAD0ZdeZkca6eQsZUplwmAHRYWCmSg@aBhLzijR4RXhOFDJZJa4mALaWysrplgadALsbyHTB86G6AXghz2EAG@8kIdkzUMaApc2H1aDDMK0LfWkA4gF0mbaKMgeEj8oHFMxkSP3PAQ0ZdeVcOl8sTvaxmS7m2tlG@nsQ0p@yj/YkrHxjQmmAkaer3jJdMXpDpadyPYop7bZquUJQQU0cF0TR9HhDgWkxeGacfmTx@XTeNIh4qkWQBwp53npiKFRQugg1Pa2DMGWKmGiA3meDWNLH07kDwM1U5tIHBJkowAfpgSJ4GgAwmTpS20MXpBow8G1fa/eBZ7F0BpeLfBCazh6CwrmDZE93/ayxMHL9aT6SyfpBWIwHUaSxRWfxwOCKqOoTAdT44YDHMSvOYA5i0y8iDASh0ExWyQDvfQHnwDTMOUiBkD5aBJmM4e0AmtgxKpQwcHlqF3VWX8v0mwjaDNX4DvJf33UtZxXGCc3tD1sZ4JTsiT3edQ8MZJasa4811@Tulm62QCw70D@zXg7Z9rCljaYqRGF@G145kRtQwLoOq8HI/XEIXBePdR0QmBS@gcChKIkEN6HgvxIAElAGCBXvOiSKt0GoHI@NdlzKUFfKQKeTUkzCjivBZEXCVD5dNswBSiF2RooBanowadMM1PSFzCeRr8wd6nzZT3pdLJa5MjUjfhd78uRJbDVWB8n@5MkzcK2h6xm6kuB6Rq40uRAugy5KkSIXxp5TCgy7jN2fe5hHiUtsthGOSp80K66cr64WLlPKuSyeeXwmQNSBZAPoND4ATyxRq6EzkZDqt1DRTKs7WfsNlM7HbVuzBBFeKjcK9wsqFIgM2sDCSaCtVnGQfZwmg5oNoyAore1@3I5dnOcuLi/uLjrJi/tYClMnqkqtBZWC/OKDTM82hzBcJs6XV9PyZSJxXoBBslWL5WJL8Xg5rUNGSiLxXTmRVDi14zEVpHb84iIGRBX0OW/3bcI3SuUTCZ9UUA4cmEEnjMcyd2XIv5W4TCRjkDYRS8EUoxaLAWXaSASHKo2cOUGgg6NXnDAbyWSE2NC0r/E7I/YhLAMTLJ58G/h343hy0jq4BunK2o6Oqkja5toIeLNLPLBDD1/jWmW7pLEaMNxCDWC07fgzI5xLG0PSn0m5NcMZ0XQQISgMxx6Uq9oEDCLuaiOYIEC/H3uKEI7fqAttwITT1NXMGakmEoOOw7C7Z@ZqQ4d8WMm0nYAHQO8Bp6UrbejYk@guJHYBCIHPs9n5MYnqDOJpVYlmNV@qIwwsbcVA@nU00tqHmtNH8oJmhVMJuwtURZUddAOVqLbL2jDm94DS6khzuQ4PfHSMSXYUJ55ArbHBtS5U9lBjwEJ5NgAazs02zHdU0Bwwlk8e2ZZxo9mmgUTObAFqYPgqtsEU8nnkBTZqNHbzmw/Tdx5yoNhMsByibRjrNHHbTptlDVM3eyZbAgBkzUyGM/au0YYigM7nwvSSOdonIlCjZxrjKR5Ucbh3UEeUSwVf@1YQMkvwmSuQNWx@pQOAB@p8vPv9FowQcjGXg/J7vhx9/EqGsEzXEQPbLAAQBlcd@QZb8nvV6o8nzEHIH3wWCfxkqrxj8nm9AgMqlEr08E@UNNzJeQj0cy@q47nm1X2LNCQ0ZYRnGRO1B2UQ@qmoDu82UMPoVDCGeqSYQDrT4EH7boPsPOkP1Yja7ptMugANI19n2Y56k0WBI4Gg64OqnIasVJuUMT@ZMABHXHMIWl1H1bWB5u6SuUs3UHUJhmUvFm1uAYJDTXUjYr4RiFc0SQWy1uhx@K0RDkhORKUn2z/Y3GoeNk52alJ26NhZXWsBB3fU5gAUT111JDb9ibIjFZCJ9J@u9SPTdGu8ua519sVPFNN4yfc2m3u760eNo/e8EITG0QZDXcGirC5OAWDyY4r2elXIDti1zYGvkTuiIRYLSHp1wmKP01MRu4yxQ2GvD4WXMHyANvhMO9Jrt1na5F4/UACuICDa5WkM6yWTCEl2ej9QQJYJJdrqM3bLC6xgoG@ln7BfB@jmxT@cSGC@k3P3iNwxho4VqtmdLFP4jdvt4qjtB@cp@DqNrK4HwQUK5lb@Sfu6IMtM1FxgH98y4eOrA3PxzUTNBfbxFTk@XFWYj24qZh6oj6xEyHAVYi6uqYg5gD6mFcIUXrkI4soU99CyhchrbvSDiXzcFcKNSxsBKlroEEEeYJ5zx4AvOzhNtJEGPJKXJ2Ixii9WsHQHJidrCIL88hmXMSAItDjH6mTckRugKIRRpEHn4IsYfjxnBFlvKk3olUFpvZBQFEvrIMDkUpC46Cc2p5KaWhDsg/N2zetNEAHDUJf2QsJRfiLehN5qSbhT5HkL2qY1DvXluzwn/kAT4iTUuwqc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vxYSUaS7gTmBI3TNBEdrTHFqTDEu8iK@wX0Qkb9YxoV5LQUw@sP6x9M18s6UURkSyGMTltYmT3cDVzGXkImLxUQyu9dmUXdAZ6WcCdKZQszF8DBi0uvQzB2BVWMRguMMlHqTKS7Tqo9HOBA1evSUwmtsTMqCWZijZI3rgLH9eeSbtFROFaandISi3WZh8ofsLYOlKmSC7rZb2ECjQBYvuPeeA2cPWPLJBL@zPmLTYBOHdoe3qakc8//0vOtAAs83TV8ak0PuOJtCNeKP7YGuJpOihn/ktSzBXQ11TiAzk@hLKtoKrCIruO@ajRs2EpdN9xR6g3iwaF5gTf6DXPMJnvOS2qg87qvecnwmReNJwxlMb2oBqBE@c@NE094HkU2Y/np6mTrqpdAgLn@BoatDavF3UEVf1Qxo0yJivKKdnnWPBcpjbH7pD/osrYF9qV83C73yqrE4yWa6otGQ1azpKS1Mf4QNbuR52zLR13aNKY9FKD3E770RoTEp3deWaO5vonE8AXkVb6/VU23s@BHbbB52dJhvZW3o8wiqexsRIB1Yew2nr/PchEG8Hie94mE6aTj/fwpDEIm3oNUhaXOZOh8ikTRFWV1pjnHT1v52zMENSRUHw1NrJZK6AY6e/phEsqFvWw@lxwKX0lcr81HyBnZNk3lQkyxfW09zgRHUWS@1f6PUwcmkDRU/nOyHng0LcM2YGrjmgNANPt3XFAWZyRXOoN9B89PMYg@Ng1Ea2ClyPsHdQHG9p66FVkiCNBRqGrjkW73HC85A0nbYvB2hwpwP9BEnRN0vfDim5Tj/tu@YLBLPt4krFA/z2FQKOLxLgMkyIgTLmQ7Rrm7f4fVDF6Js3Kv@dP@h9mluqrxBVaZ04Q2vPSd5pf4ldca2bfuZT8Xpuqdy2PjdcWOQn1fyvZWhH000H5tv4@xghQHN2HP47n5XDNNMUI02G47B7fjJRKItlhKHsgZZU9J6pl8q9rAI/Dzb30O6i@BfPrxV7vtiS5S@LLU87Mg1ZPB@U99dZ@/pLnEDWZRtXoULORwbbebJLrF48XEGYQ@DS8vzKbefKlDKT5caPhxrAbvdvlbH3/BlDykPU9YYUa0y6NSh/mKBSBodrc3375@S2/Hhuna8TSDNoV75UiVDjXusqiGf6nWlSls/J35hCzuW@Xjx19aE6VOdqeQetKxW3BnIzLe5IUHSdL2@e7B58Y6FyohqLwkyYBeKhkdCH@iRmjl9Vahy80feogFF0DTr5F1WcufLOAoXcwsn2ITgO0TGbsGcMrYnGDdHuaGgcPU65vuX1bLMzUUiM@VaJVP6yIjWhszsqfR/S77cGJsyPzQEoDMZXtL9AShYN/juBmEICNWPC8DE3e3@pGhRaUDygRbVrJ402768TOvmHJvUEXKnAtM1Q3TH@PkTpeUK0ZZr6t7QMyNKORluA9TRuG/1SC80oOWLXAgvMFw6aQlrdhwwXfJwRM0ygHs6m3Ufmz2Ez0yNTwhmT@SOjVciA/qVJJozUZBly7Lbnfoghj7BTy5lyZuVRduQ6qNlSdYU/RqXlx/BVMoVH8flah1BuacEFF2n4skywrhWdEj3WGIildWCC0lcHKnkf0eyVztXQ8R4PAo1M/M6JzmRpkeGBdJYGfd3A34kloJA25JoGTKlcxe6pOCfRcW1ShD4kX721i7nE3R0oPZWfEHhMdASmCdzOxmdygXO@kWKV7zBpQzK@AP84K0DHuVbHjveci/D1uA3tORw8im1eH2@jBfSLnTqTnbtk8wV1z@ibfaOv9m3qHL7voe4BHOnysx2PVQLK31eca9y/R/IomMv1nTB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@cbZLdx734Gk34R3rLQgQjy@aMeDIZuIRGP3Q32nrw5hZHJM17TUNPkeAtXR4sN/59ubdw9iDjvTVLvDNx@g@U9xtZauslsNinDlhFe851uTWrqp4BbRR5R3oIz3/Br7VNu0v2j86Cmma1n0aFr60KEfsvOmu/MNmKtsm0r6NcyguXzfB2dZtWe22n3tS0VqqYpraNdZz5DDvY/OS4UwppprLL2JwRldA1rZ4wwyQS0cf4yP3YfGv9DyzNzabwxte/xlwTC5mu/bW/kqAToeyl8svM6JpiEfNzZ5G3geWaoQ67QPchMp0Kgsp9UcaCXyg/afiT1cQnrRguEDSs9UvakwoTWyb7FfioV@suRpoc0KED7PePGQINwR8g1mhfGdYc9JfJlx@x3QqfBnLsJGDw878dUkRzdvQ9Zm6PqKIR5zR2V/RfGxhZHioysj88icyYq1zbQ6fNDepWuWw39ZupufW7zZxfpZqPH82a9oso7a5b9f0vQGpo0b20GlSLdt1WmjGRylMZeSXAQZZg@kclpnAbAHO7f4s3sD5ukqkyNe@t2@2lNwo9uehnvedGd2EATM09sEvgbxm6HiaG@GpqvOxTm9XeBrUL5Welp7Z6IFPIQedcWuKP6Y6BQYNNsQt33Nof3FnmN@R@IsRivvs5HTlnb/nNvjhpGQniS2ebL0LvO2g/oOtPVjvDI3r0ktVCy6Pyj4NJcMqOI5t57zt1Y8ZlW4HQ6soSMe83Mf4GmBsB15cE3hzq0GUjH9EYQw6yu6O9/WHDKmgn4lRsbAOTdLvkPgiI6e@YcUnJTYWwdhmi1OSDkZ7xhilPYh0pEFbws7i@JBiiGKYte0M4zg4nElmUwkIjwRGrN7BoB5UHQQDA@J8DNmDtM1xyVYrcvOz9ni3Wg1tyrfsxqTViV2ecmx4oeOLGyNLDrFdcSTny8ql7XFWDodW4xdGKssF/PBVR0acS64MgHb1ejByxuQgBkK322Kbq/GVX4IxunTATNQYDqgCJ0aZJ9ApYof5eDnhE5wFf3f/WVHnLuD2ZIDGgQIUSAIHjs1B2rfvH3G8xW5NyxLwXN7iAP6nM5PkaQ3GgyYATQmftzOvGWn2ydlcYhHnHEFzyEfUf1S8MbFOTtuwXV54/HS@NspRcZ@Kq9SbVMfDgzQUTtu38mwY4121w7tYJscuBDMcG1U1Dsptss6Kq5V0qZpmpvqpnlNpx@wJP/uL/nRJdo6Lba0etnTkcVQjrhDWqbzQu22OYRSe0g@qbYpQOJIZOiBQ7T6wDit8vAEbiimM1XAkWnvRBFlw48VbTSOWXqLxfD4Lh5UqGrd@GLj6MXb89xl7Uc2yKr//hfZxJ0gnPRdulJypBTzQKr3yFjh6CJEB7ExJi2OJJ6hv69cE/vKb3l7AIkUzmS4tdzjMdO0RK@hU6F0CNLnRnG3QBzd1M7e0aIBHSglhlVv6WgR7ec0UDLhSU3DgQ4G3gSh5r2uthgfcuNE@thlRcgQj2cp4OJHUGmnNR6TwSSLI/aZ9ZHJ0m3c/Qs@TkgdT2YNauve5pVCeItRdlNtDWld/SafyRdqVJ3FZm2tTi5b7Zh4QvL8h4tRPpe@GK1sXWYdj6gXF6Pvcvl3QHUT5k2LT7PY87b2N@8WM/Xc58@OMmaSdB@r8m1QICYW7w53D7eOTxonp8fQCvee@Nk27YESyBrkItrP2zd1OnsKdLE11fkG@eP7ADweZ4sKW8M7ERKJSHirKoEKWktpaZE7Q6JpIvUXks9L76ih@FkAIdO6GvM4ahc0WmxDYDakGlZ@aOEJWibSilOAxGUaynjsQD5hcLPZHFlKpJJYDYiVBmJ9JanYw5V9xsO@hmJfxPI42Z7NBUGK@fmd@/G8inNJcP87qbcFA@VvX2@O5fF6E8wj9QZQP9RLs93Y3Ts92ppMBjxGT5K6tUpR7NHmwhl7GrdreMce6TiLSIiGnZrEJErAvWIwowsvWqp7q0K1hHBsD3hi4lAqvxQJGBMoU8NbQy6rnBbxOJUAdZAqVmtqC3lXG4WK6I3RIXR3vIq@ENiWfNRewTOSwBylOyAy@PGqgVgFubyud0hCXMjrmBNWf1Jej8Oq4RgNOiKlemCo8kcdh8F/aFTyXPlLNmJiOJMvWZrl4aurMD/q@7CJKh@j2CInhLTIyy755cX7B6BMnSuF5lO07UnskodRWlcsPOwsoPdhDrPKPg5NOpLjCRNfv7hFbV3hV21Q07YVrA0d9TFcPLjsjVuEb3f7uIbaGVfNSL6HeW5o4EAFQKGLL7ZGoIgDs3VJ1vMj9Jzkpjit7Q2VZHBzxOlMX0tw2I3mkEEOG6GLOo4OkhJrIyqOd8bQYSzW0B3QSTowfPMbVkg5ydB2XL4nN20wKQo8mfFVxhSTIgjr1GZP78JQetuGYfUDT7xIcITZCeGMrT1Jp4FyPc1gjqHBNMldRbshzfRXmWsPcXW7HptJ4hVhlVzpvjvQQ4Bz7jG4ULM//eM/43cXXLjg/kPhHuXWwfdHwtcF9z/yYmQZfP/E9@XB98fc90MWm2z2wPZMObGfi4rx8vktiK33dveQOWSwxPYZKKMQ6VFqIB9pBtBAG0BD31C7ITjPIWiWAE/8/C00O/AKtDmqLKilUH6qfRnHo7ir2Sxq9DiLytAWV3XErZV0MvfjEG@kAMUqWyqWluUsFDJ94yGk43E93FPJESYSqyDnIjeaVfvQauMOeCY5bUVXa6Uqb@/sovJDQfrgF3QRYCNc@T9nkAY3zfspIK4uksUXlaScwKQ4OMXkGMqpjsnZBzS8ODkAJIHBhne@CFRIU5AKeNNQRy5pQWNvUtPCe4PQqqLye0k8RGlAxHHjvQnTXSzYJYmbykOdLhNuBukMwY4RbFWax4DnP7AL98K4FPdnMGCmX81hRwPc/3DOpRqcs/DA4OxtDvHpuxiwNuz5sWHibtptKC2L57P5QlYuJUIcKglUUF7svp8BJXRYEABtVbsyLaexsbX78uDweOZWAoKMTYPFWKy@lrxIZ1Lnl74j5pd7kqjr29nj1@vbHinDpQrWmhEiWHCeLua83KZL@kDuZ3x76mzeFDGTkZz7WsS0upPepv0Ys9iD2GwIcINvi5vJNZ64uz@/XKtfGNGZ7D/Pu6klmllC5gLXhUP3tMSmi4lF3PU23Z7g/W1OxjtwkZeCe4j8oyDcHwQ/fK@AfxtccLmAt703Qsf@/FN/kcwDG3@h7pksz4pO1vOCeeUFWeMVVcaiBhm2IzP7BcKlYaIusxfXiXMtPpEOuF3Iu3bM4ZAOCWduOaIbPnya@XAnHkbs@sFxf3HOvQ@l07VW5FYcyfROBfnHMTOOpWtuPBExBMT0@aBZSOfRU/M@mFI7HzH/QIyDeuAoQ3etxOlSmtvLCL90gHl3AyTpeoHDIdDt0LRYYBnbVD3XEehJbHMIWbRxkvVyOAC4Lj2OVBwtVNCc0pAY6BnzinKOB@oFJTKDTjE@SmT66qij9WDEiSdSIJq@k@XgYgIFT9aDrtSaVwM0NVl9BeqATVNYw3P9o8RahbxBBflyB7udH2xcRgAZJm0lVrk1InZqeHfIYMOvsljKp0wrkYplGJ8diethaM2TjEsZttHHHWJkzuh2NVLDwsd9@WDe1exBBmsFwwxnoRe4PzTMNd90R0SIMsq5ktGMjjqK43Hc1UukE4THbs9uYglphsXpogpxLUFn@sYKTxYqrhBKwW0PU/KuUvHl3KRoqFQyfSeCR6tgogE5Hrv2HjhBRYh3B4rF4kO68sNhGUbe@EXcSDmunWDpOg7Xt8xgySTZKeBBETAPQdAuuTQ6Wx3HG7Li2Ro0EoY6RgcfnzSLncuZzCW4KZMEW0Qb5QZoU2jdS0Rg3glJVgkt6Bfwt4ol4rcRZsSthIuUbYRO3QPU3GiSU70@yRegBdWa1Z8GR5xDAoZTtVJZFa0xKe0rDPhibY5ABLRzpLin9wN9xeEYoBrKaIDasNWOBvLy@SvVMFQgEPDMAC9fVIbAZHYi5d0Lmgpu/qIcoryIO@K0DRR08kawrdidboK6tpitkrmreg9qzYcL1Gu6QrMZZ//rbCZbvYsv6rVxFnTNRD2@2K/JycJSMrloLMUXDdS2nj5FK9n9IihzzQxMOkcAlF7UE1XgZ1D@aotGdVFZiy92avklSgFemPbeQYIfnWzmblG5zy4@BWUpBSE2FzrxRYcu68hlMvI9lA97yGI2BTxzh7dO0G2fmP2ilkxiGTKLTSzAj9mL4yQNmxfHWTLIVYV@n@0NRHebUsX8lpi5pZQTUASv@gNWEQcssWmq6QEH94EV5sU9oP7xjF/h1lJGK@KqE55QSZMxXy9YhJxGmSuETJzflgIEHMWBiOhNKYkECJPf/CYqlxiTnpUKcTP5rJirJmNFGabeMGeOPgc9PLsk2dLdxWb6hqnp2HlXKWY@Xh5eHx6@S1zEWYXFohsHkrws/cAqefZ1nxWWf@DDfptPNLqUjUSzS/LTlWz2w4cPMOOAz3k9UwfxwT@J83Ts8jy@wlh9ZWUpVSovpZ7HmqGCJeL5fOKYZdmFpmmW0@nA1@zT1bzxKP88e0Z5wZQe/hkPE/kLh@dBEBEa/VY4pRhlFyuKspRczj83qlC0Cn4KTAYn/pbhK7NikW3h52/@j7/507/5E/r7U/r@W4Vds0/wue4y/Cf3p07IraC71f2El5nA1KJGcsGKxYqF2PEPMfYf7fOEyfVnK//hTw4@Rt1oPZ89s@HpRj9GS@Uod4IDfAXPdxOtR9cQrHQfHWdrtRo4V/7D/wbp6y8BD8aM1@CnXvRwlcbRerpGST5H6yVwyPk85Pv//OIXkWh9FP0UlWU5Oqa/ZjQn46f8VH7KGDiy0kpZMs3nXnnLpZH/8cKyspy/CNoz1NzYtH5wH/KBdmVmdBKU3D5XMcEN5PgWOLyXtvTk@YdNxlQYavGzuvp8huB7U/6jTBo@GdENRuhJj7wqRMu1VJNn7/NqNOSYqrD/y0Tdff83wkWi3h2M6XOle8lGoc9FVC4vHzwfffWHBYX2iBgNaOdnzqbDPKr7HuZ1evYtcJHoj7XakYt/r1v4d3iMfz9XzLFn8HkCf/QPH9@Lv08oRAQTyOznyW/RXSPR8@j55eWbPv3Z@Ldj4F/rI/7tfcK/Ny7@nbTx7@gN/j1UmUh0bW0tmkwegWooePZrPqfwzWSawufxLqL7nX7Y8kHp4HmERdOXyfT9/Xnmh1GyWhX/oDRVfR9@uAuKdXmfTq/9UE8mz6l453VRzrX0ZR3KyotMPz@sAeLk2vnaWqZZr9fTlz/Uz9cmE4l0z58nsZ8@h4T1y/PzSPQO26KGP0v403bwNy9JWfLiYAGjcwVcjJz0EAGMLk9HfyT6Ye1DPPks@Syn525y8rV8/do8CP4PDkYQoY1yV6ad6@f6cgckIsupp7lxbjzKDcwDuQNOFf5yA3Bque4o18sZOUOWx6MJVA//Dw5M9/WBCdhMSOmOci4iznXh2Ts4eA34upD3FfxpuVxuBIUc5W7gP6ejoKabnej5QzNxETln0gcVRv@MHMvkYplSLKZdFkvWx4u7@3zpo5SKNS/OY5fVaNa5uMhy7Yjll6t0r9f9fbO5tb/ZbGaRj9YWk8@T6efwqdWTa@LxLFqvPrtYTWP7cf7LNKPZtWcX9UIa3aUkNFIewtayyW/8BCjhWX9yEYEJ39kZfs9ub265ixzkujg782PxJ4tB5KIg@ABodm76CQcDTfP39N85@M/r//Upi59fJhiL392vxemTwL9E4u7@7l781hPxuPDE1@APA8CPSe7u6@gkoDtwnccTl4n7ex4Gv/HEGkdYxzzW6pQ4AIQOG@W5XsSqoOHVFuNioeziYpTLJaotCPHN68pnWnNJVGk3ymIL18lgNiAvJQikuFytLgv3SrlaLQu3XCpVq0s@VA48wglAqqO0q8jo1WgCi8DnBnE5m0erSgUmXHJhba1UrNdLRfCUyol0PIdRdLFi7CJmWdZFLEPm9QydLavVGratjMkqswzzvQvoXjHcoVKrFPES2Yps2ulKIRFLJH6QBep8gpdBOl@MRfkOFSaXVyjw/lJ1olEKi0ZVJ7aYlaLApQ67u48StdhyMRFvjdUEWy7Fy8mK@Ks9SbC1bH2Jib/z80JyeWll6fnlZaAGYKeu3ik1@b52p6zilP6@2hYXDepmjylPnxYqnz/L5Vz1ItJsbjZOGk28sV2SUGJajGEoyYcIru9ZduycDDDFyuU5Fv7yIhZbrT7n7VAusmisKuDSMZA0rFyhOkZhlqd1cYPpCAWx@K7KS/nCk2xx9F1pKwda8ecl/Jyfn5fz5eQSSKKlSuXy8pJCPz@hNOeDUfeS7ryppc/lUvEyjerG1ai7BIWVVwrRpYhFu3lWcqyDC6I2GrSeQGBfcVgL164dVde9yx1vTVvv3GodFbAf7jU2tk5S@TVAmd9ubKTyx6frURm9xcBP0QX0H201Ng9OIcHh3lbjeOvF7tut00MId2BQA2LBZ3CoqEO1qd4Oh7fob6r02dAc5epKsawm8JY16v70qz/46Vf/3U9//sc//fkf/PTnf/rrX/7pH8D3L@H7x/z5x/@6UsTfX//yn/wvP/2rP4fAfwvffwPf//PXv/znv@Bf8v81fP@vUNhfi28Ijn@BlIDtj379yz/5i1//8h/9C/j@S/H9F9Pfn/7Z/87//2/xh84//@mf/TX@CM8f/DEg/Lu/@hX@/8lf/d2/@RX@/6//09/91f/wd3/0P5Pjz7jj//2X/5r//u3f/4O//W/@6d/@/V8@8PsHj/7@8ivCf/l7CPn6cn4Nnq@p17eG/PJnlee3oUaQCzHVn/7Dn/75PwBu/Wfc99@DD/79qD/0PX5MkqZf6WQQ@IeMfc6CgpN7/tkHBZT/I4ZCMPs8iY1Cc17or3/5T/8Cgydg/0EYQ06ehV1EYD@3PwTYf@UXLAz7hz/96hc//cV/@9Ov/uynX/0RCrH0ciXVSKXlL8xgALD4FXAIWPoaOACEwWVtjT1hTyJ5cDxZQ8NCRE5@@AAkfQIuUJSXIsUC@CJyndwyuiEhzDuW@Mw3ifN5@I4iyxXwgQOCRuSAqCRErSdZrVZLRkY1iCNQ8GKaEauXcY6Kun0N8GIinibVLIPeyEbrhAVS1pJHrLlUG/GESQyoEwaGBcKgI0nOS8lybRMyrI02GeJC5MnIB3h@qNXLtVEd0f1IRQAcyXXIEqBqWLpR/Ufw1wgnwEdGmz9CUcq1ZLJehpAaVZVySzUpT7lIlaO6JxnVG8MZQ0vXs@eMfSfJZYnPsYCUTEDjbzKAfkaWhmcQf5FcEtWhf89J3yVMD@00IvrwMB7/DIMpvQAAvOk07lmCbzqNpXkO0SOOKknZwiPJMQDlksIk4wfQyJqMJKl9k@SB/KEMX/dZq4c8iA6rs7i4CK61ulSQDkBZZ/b1quMqNpr/SWtZZVKpImEwbhdRFw9JnV/aXIJfGf63ntA2Tk6OpchiDIfvGPPySCcL5rIZpdJ7VaO6LFHJkwQXiQbhXIWkNRzQ/ZZZIhKnG4oTNCdULdBaIq@d3ro5YvFcSpJScqnCTaFiyvjeXF2t/Sgvr0TgSf4hXo4srumFZsAX5mSwdyFB63fpNepp4AQVoxSp18U6FJMj9eOtE0hwcsDkfC7DQA28W17JLxeXi/lCqVRcycvLpcpyqVgugIQq5Yr5vFxZXq6UKyv3UKDn0M9Tq0ut4lr97818/qu/N@8zPxQ/kfo7Nsqww8M36ftIfZROZ/NU5JpcXKmOa1AQCorUSXviOuj4Lu04DJsnckHbmO5wdw0ULXKXRlZdgA@LLETYAgTBBzCjFZ6JpeHdg6pYI8Or5/k6mSQXgRkSkQtgBo4tYoU/EWy4pyBtnsrcWSwFzhw6Iyd47GIfMoB2MNgebjB0TXZi8o1s62r7AYiNPn/N0oZtgr7582HWFeOaR21qeKVb2/WjdhS8s8UZaG7/AYhTa4Bn1FT794Zha9CCAqKhkAOsw4@tm@Y8gBV2evhALV/7x7NwyY3OZwH40e6LnZPQ82SrsbETKbH1g/3NqUdRABXZ3tb2ie9d4bFe0qKP4v3W3t60VzxwzvCEFVdSKRB88IPPFH3omVn8wQORMw@PiGoml5JTzbF6l07ft1S8kPuYXznu4gp6lxhfNx05FuupAxjIoKvKwM24mbVn6jBLWsxt5HBxIPsZZzlNNV8cs0WQe229AjNGtlasl6JSUSrX8uVSDuaAtSTdi9414ixRjZZwSnheuayNWIGVzy@tqBN5jdu1KjI/SqA5kR2YmwzwTmg8c@xGbLUD85Rbg05JtPD9K0OLPRgIDwxCp631@iAAb00fwAF@bikKg@@3fgCHGv64jwe4PA8Km4nRZ8Ejt75VxzfXMN9uw6XCGW7jpSM83towjTHOauQEpTG9lYfhwakWXmRPB0BhmOcnOunaeRVkcyUSwfUwrctykQxZufKVcrFcKeTLqXKlvFyEGWMxJedT8kp5pQLMkpPLcqlcrMip8nKlsAySGWKLlZVIFKSX1s1mYeCRJYmemtHGCybX8KZOM9OvR6LQ8NiX2AjfYxZV/IBhmUmF8kWOQUIpgttZl0Y1Cd/zl8O36MlSRFJYm0W3tzdy29uStI4eNOlt5CSpg55iOZdbWZcklWI2YPTIQ6I@@rZKqMBKkoaejcb2NmK4Qk@@jDgk6ZrHcI/ueVYAzEBPoUAasCR99NHlALnJS1SmVC735HLrG5I05MXDw3UA1@C@ZSrsFnowAhNt85gNiJOkF16iHJBBOuJwIqsdr76NhiTtck@jgSheUuWLvFKv0NOgDySywQeML0k9cPRsmMlLUgucyP6S1AZXe6xA2ABceG@F4SqSNOb1wJpI0oiglfa1BIqdCId8oDw7O0rf7ag9/hnb/NmGqF2I0kbDre3WixetXq9ljxtbL44o6uXLHeVqPLRbvZZI2GrCx8RUEHU9GE9/VIxqNhV9ftQriDKmoprjpkolbCofoWTi08OMBs2XGPUSouYtAAmE8BkAcAs/6wN4ristHuV9KIqeo1ZLqiLLYtfpxolxlRQ9WixxhyIxrjwDTX1ZWkXhanZBvxqWE@nis2FZKq1Iq0vwlJ5JBXCO4rlYjjEpdiFJCRCKz6SVorQae/YsHXsqP2PSSkValVZWpET1HuVyPHHXjY9So1oOArLZNezH2PPgCSqL0DdO1JGb2VFx80U7nT6b@KytnQEcng7H83D7wwFbZ7ckOnB3vLeZuFlbBzmRqxp4fFhF7@IoOorUO4qrwMxj/W64uipg76u92jki@Iw/a2nprH4mXbJwvsWVHJTq1GjnV9bWzj9fgtpVk6vjKIwk@XJ1hM@V5bDCtagrjrsor@RXz4eL52n58smT3OfemvR9nTCj4kV/YRMdyKoqhHnU4NIt2tU@QDxbTfM3F8jlUiKD27WbZrdJt5OzDyEhhgmtmmgzicXx1SJ8b0g8FlvJx2KJWBWAn0CwaAxqbK@1JBCU0FqVPCh2VVt1h6BG5Kr3Xln8bLhSWZIj0ftIBy@oXK5EoneR@7v7tbo3Sr9i47GSTHvep4z1kjC/yNJSAC4iPCFXOlN/zhq1Ru@oURWgjQ2aBQBDXPBjROnsk29dcEiu1X/gz4s6LsBBPhEqPl@Uy64l69l6vX4RkSQpKvn24nIR5g44wf4xSjZgtnHXHRp0xnj1NRJMWeWaxvll4sd9Tb8rF9J12usSB3a@jybXsriSlalniVrtA1rnjUQNUzjRGukCd8dBfS5KOFFRmXVc@WHlh/IPr08PTg@22fPcanm1zElBC@/PUyk5JseAtM9h0NKOtiJR67NZlH80Xlajq1assBwrTChIFzVxijaOnBA/R/v6eeHy8hwmIZcJ8NVq@WdysZxcXpVXEtE6nubLr0Tr5IBeky5EL7mhOr68whLgIbtvXo7WsyJcXpETUScdFSbulSKoQNHy6w@fYQIpXn2o5cmVzYpSLd6v3cN//f4c5lj3NNW6p3/8ycLPPQeAfwT3PfwRfEJwYZgg/vLH9Br/X6OfjQNeZqkEFI9@qNWhYX9o/tCMRqKVWD2ZjeFLeMVHTF5QnVky6E91lvDvhyBgCTSwJd8H3rUlVqzD3F5dymazF4k3eVBHKpVSuRSN/Gb2k12CedbSQoPF@FUdXA2it1F7x0ViE@9Qwunx0kJ68/hg4xXMQkEPUg18lxzbONjPYBS@7iw479PWVcXWx@J9Z2OEQvXpZOMQ32d8unlIac7opBeF0ixY5LK421kVrxtI3TA5U2D5XK6YzS1n5SKTy6u5ldV8iSm6ChPsrZElXIuYlFG1NkxrzHXW@EaCEi80EAbj9jSYfDjqKntxuEcp6ND30sLm1usDdrC/9z7jhfLwk53dY3Z8sH1y1jjagnq83jpmUuOY7R5L7Gz3ZOfg9IQ19t8ziD5q7J/sbh0jgmwE5RWuQXCC@RodW3PGTtYdW6pDat1EsGO2r1V3MlyxLSWLN89NBht4F72KVzhPhg8NmMF1whrjcWMB5nTDNr4Ftn2tdDp2BI@YaW22gKPtwpJq455NqZ9zVlhx@O5Tzi4@Ye3l/dgKa@f2jcLaCtNz4o/py4PCEXvy5MmFIVWFNI6Eq@ErrOEg3MgMYUGZdr/fWoiXltkSqKn55UQQs39wuJDzfAtnRycLsh93tLmQ9z272wsF37MFvmXft322uVD0feuNVwulINn@xsKK79vc2lgo@z5g0oVKgHN/c0HORTxi3ZhaZ4HeoxPf3t3bYksAlKhOxKJdAh1TwUCI@NBw@Hl/JDlbWrrtm/gSb5i7jKegO@qXoD3wCagFVCrOka6XKbZkWvAzUAcADMlob3Gc3pdk99opgRWvmIcRJHIXWcAKLWCFAH4BT5oiHHtSY/kEg@iFLl9HjfPrZFJMOnXoPNl3DlvD8b8OzJCiO@vpXCGkUMVrryIL9wJlvEu2my5trCRQGUoq2VIigQeX9k/39nhmFmRh2nGJIBl5pDk4TQuwQRXhF6sOobxxeLNQWyCtFoQGga/mitxPtGZkujWRFFDPhYU2IJik7o2ipxjqUylc8EO86OEbogEYosGdAxc/sRWPt7GuPdVtU4ESSMytg21eQ1wyrLHJVk4wzJQoRdF8q/Xnz8zzXbiTXnvSa8Q4boGcF4vj4yWtIWwCwxa8o3IEQUd9KeUCckwyCamhOhQXqtcCEB2@/GSwV8o6ZJSLsadPqRxr4KvEKAtMl6QcWRpBEIEgGJEPkflFe0LFTSxkl3ABnr/XFomI4wi/CK419m81AMk6XdCpVvV7od@cC4bquNUpgSyiuh1sa3AX8k3wo3gETk6xFnSTFPMi5RJG4rQgxdQU60LwlExtagZwrmoHMtFjBeiM1Pr7m7yF@BUeFM4DqMYg91apwUBYPMXuS4y@sNCyVeW66kGBPCQo4FtkmjgSgsM9nu5ok5It8f6CbImpvybl7vaqx0c8NbCD4DQiK5665rwiqkuB9QBoBr9Ahv23Bug5S3JkyaSA8LlMgG1NwqXTHO7e48svVGJruhZPvrkWKJYfrMXWV1bjt6sFDGsBi0AtQMTHAW8SoOlnsjXz81DAWEgoqDY/DwUMoAEvQR@fQPAV6WHIDdKnvz09DNKr010Z@i20IJcKPMmktz3p7Ux6sftCiMJgSpBfZp9ZC11yCVx4UpeVwdHhsnIyYXfSS1aDGlO9NF1fAvMcgOdQVHIwZMBZYYwSJOPgpdXKAF@cUGON7ebu/tbJZCziyzhNUfA@vhOY8khMgokCYbwTR0/CL1G8i0Tg@mb8kOeRIno2j0@OthqvU1C@BFsLesC0DgA/oidM1ODeywFCDbUN43EnxeLHDbaUYE@xZCkmLAPo@eosdNNRAdWDOXaGVp6yynEQ3z/Zk6LYIyNzspLiLJ5gny8uYEjNrTB5YH0uDArGSqHDxoUVVHY5Hl8HEVLeEzD7vGtyZQMhgT0VvD9ibmZXuRxbtgvMVfugcY9y9ix@qtc9jm00LHrnCS2TJmVOlV4rjbJF3KgA4@KkavO4FkljI/IBhmI3hjAczsk0lST9HNmTYj0Fi5elo35rWb6k0U6WJc3LskaZzpbhN8I6B9OlyNSZUbqYwrRcS8FjlSLywEK7ySEG2ZEIt6eE7ieKm3hdvZtYpXslUKY0YSTX3GYz7qh6F99NO7TbMOSjuuwIMPxgbIZHUkdCx2SkIA/qT5MR/FXveGMcjDpTCOkVuTW6DS1OOUYifskcV7WoVKFioE0M39EYzhBfMx72Q7Pi8aRQiROrQiveVrA/eMjOJ66U4TiGTj81JxjE82yoz6Zz4ny2mROHN4fNS@Idm50TdzUczCsBCIYHYsTBtzkxhnkwLwG/kSWIuDwPEfA8TODLy3hiftNDv5ps8dCVOkT/E3uoivthdg9CLAjKpeDAUFtHN1Vg2raGlwBPI/KP3kLK@CgROgXss1Ui4CTFaWvaNHoPk0BEx9jonls2WsW3fI@@k/PlRCqEMIQRr3wbKPpDOFkIKZRwDpIofx0z8yydjo8aWXAab5A@g4fYjQ5M74IEpvUIPMYGsNj4HvAC3inkx/jMPKfLBehWZxmHwtHcjs0vT9y@9BC0Vwk5ESbob5t9@luzT4fyxz75s7KusfPJclwmQ3581XxQR6@D/6yMvFJP5pb4phqHuUZVrx9gX7xRI5QNP0k/ma2PRkggn6e8qhB6DPhKIYG4woi@Qb5Q84lzvvNSB@PPUo2lZT8Nl3hBbyCreqjwEbwDoNnECzGbTboJrdlEy1KzKfEcaODFAS886IrOxuMyoKU2TYqNS2lFSknpdON4Y3c3rRlSit@jWpMc17TVJl5oJKU6MFGqSSSwmgjTV3WrJoktUYrDKLX0cB6NUB5QwS9nQkA8F3qFdvimyy9n1w5XyfyKKplTmQW3731FbkeUGx5Kfiwnm19j5WW0AX5XxaurbFVDQcNviBUvQsXrCyZOzaNJXxSB5@uQpc/Buwp4kejRxDDR1njon143W2Nk7ZO8WzykmUs3RG9HUw8iCDiVc590SO@VYHSjU0cVehaZhzJScEOfKFhG1DTE756Cxi9BCAa0yZs9RHlTnm3SQTPmVFEDwWJaWPlzCS/@gAY4NC349S//ALd//Qe48QIQDPJEHbjx9g9M0RUOcREIuOgqEHgCe0vBbYIDZaQNhmi4CR8vF5pcUCwc8rEmNOpT5KT04xRFiIyO17LGBd5EUlqVoOoOXTsyffUIws@7fSRxGZkVsnT/LRYzpDrMQzr3PpNE6nfQSCFFDEWzI0oDaVMSk7gSQmnl1UuYfIZ4xxMxqD5PhZnc6omIoCYpP30wXoVuL6lNTC@QIjB54IUJEnArU/j9TaTcJ1Z9FSRosTAUV9zmlBt3ND5Y8DAGT1FLRB6ZSf3/Zp4UbpL/TKdK/@knRTNTn9/zVOaRKcw3z1Z@h9OC/6LQ/xeF/mco9L8zbf4BlXwa5WyPn1LXv6iGf7v6RTJvDMOG3btB01v@5@hhvyNFYOWb9ACv1OfyY7rAl8dnD00@PKz/zFE68pvsSad0tm02Go2TgWwfvWj0Gv3G0Xvwr@f2kmdXy@ubt@sv1juNzc3ey97Gvvqm3Fjes169K79/0f30UQXtfefg5fefdKvdj7w7sm7P1MPbglp2GsPhx92dsbuzfjrYOC6@X7nNbenF7rr6cVN3Nl@fvHt18qJ4nLz9@PLw5adBbuAcdnNKZVDYeV16uzE@MyLFG@20s72nHQyOO1un@cHepvZ@O7mR2zuuvJFze1u33xc2bpPFXHbXenXw4uj0qrX1vX60u/e@s/HRVEofr2@t3Wyn0t24OnobOSi8kXc@Hhz0tvKVFzvZ282u1cnld3S7ePXu6HD99P1O/5WyNdgunlbeXY0PS/03b27c/WRv@aw0fO0sJ43Gmzf5V8aLm5uto0hLMU/sgnpmvpGt29tDszJYUV/t7/QGb2zZyB4U3yaPBye3m1vr@seVUeH0/dmb2@Xj98PXb15@f5DTjo9bW0rJanXyx1cny5H2oLCbvDndOi0rLzpnbwY3uzvF95vZ1311v9E51K9f9Ha@N48P93YbBWdoyHsbN/r7F/2r19ebG7u6eXitG43lbFE/6bw/OIicvtRam@rOO@dl46r/Pltcv15@n@xYL06uPvWvX64fnx6U86PDcc7ccI5aO93R5lEpX8629Y9Hn7rma/n0TbJ0c/Uyr71vfHIjhU/jYmVPf68OjJfJdu/70Uc9mzyV5Y3vdz@9f3@8c2O3Gsbpx7fbR1f2645x4Bzkjl6@et3Sr8vulfW9cXwst3Mv1OvXyZwSGZ3uONBG6olSXDkZ7L2xRpvmx6Pd753Sp@TN2XVB3bw@etv4eJRr3RrWO8Pe0wYbuc6B0nhrulvD0Yt25eb0ekff@3jgvI@83pKLxW2z66x33y5X3mVfJLvXL96ty8ej3L5x1F0u2ftv35xp2lb/3emno3Zx@61VHrhG782n08FWcmtv1P@klnMt/fj9tRE5LR4fHeZvjVfawN3eOXpdcg9ye28POztjufFGlW@NlY1xcXNklwpnm@/s99c7hpV9r30cHubUm2TnveUuv9Fa3fZbrT14FTl@2T/dP3x7u1ss2S8GhrZ@WM7t7@1s7Pc6y6/Gu6@HW3utq86L3XfqO@ukdJ3fWj8rbb47Lrgn16/cSvtmUDgsJ0/0gds7TUZeDvvDlcMz@@Pb0ffLjUFLLRzp783xijzYeGnlR28bWwefeteHlrkvb@fH2dM981rPfTq5/bTjlBrjZHl06g5M90QeFeU3kcLtJ8t9ab18c3yw/vLg@5fKsqadKVfHbzu5wmk5q/Xtwm6p9ELe2u4OPg4qqvxp83VBKQz6SWfvOtvZ6Jy@PbvWrwavBlftSLnitNd3vx8q5lYrL@fer3e3iure@t6JrJ72Xh0vb@7nDt91Dk8/jk46G@@Gp28PtNzW1cvKXm/53dHbyquV70@cE@XMfPfK3o@MygXTkUuV4m3huFI@6NvHhbOrivv9q6vSun7Wkl/u5gfqtma/K4/L19an/m3v9ljNtXovNj8qR90tkKSnhzmlOLzeHx1HCm9PBjcr1nry/XX71TtD1stn2kr25ONV5brff3W72V4@a3z6qBRfXKmV4@1sS98uvkgebbw5vOptnn0qL3dy63tvlXejrb77PvJmR9u8qpxdH4zG8pvt4/GgkTP04s3xWfHmxFw/Pts5Lvdft@xua@eqD7JhMD69uh3e7Kgr/dFt@VX/6q2S23tX3jCc5cNc5KW6O@gcnbx610h282rFvTl4v2@dlc9Gxddl86xiHpS1V43ui9Gbg@5WbsXSzk5Gp1v97PqGNiiDTDnUT@2Ngzc735@9tHKRvFFa/7RhFlc@Jm9G70tn2cPk3vB9@yQ/OLPtnXeavf3u5vDdq@PGbnK3NX5xeK0cvN8qHu9vbDgvk9taSR3vFG6dxkZB75oRZ7A@2h/ZVqXw/fVeD0YCs1PpvDgpnBlOo9G93S0fbzUaL5zW7ktlNHrRXYExAj9bZ2/NWuQ3/GaxCL9UjD8UfqlBZOD0WuYI5CU/iBWh4zEROh4T4QdiaDs032n8m@xS5CR80IXePsgNPMMWKGusY6LykGG7/k2dePl@ig1MSK6hq21a9ES0rq21hi76HFOHX7JX4VEveleSOrJ0U8P3muAd6zgntVV@ngzUl0zkwGCDMc43XXXAj99o@GoScbEmXcvO3wBDF/tFFtpt5r1RKkPXRvrvl/oACoRl9NJ0T2iPpdPtrq70HHDoHXJ9iBz791hjDrqmoPEDs5D3moqcK4qtqaiuUuFO8I0q@y@YbvJL370ZhwLKxJgudEAjFV3qoOILKh3tRtXHdIu/2slE@I7Pr9oFGQ7DbdyTYXS54dTeUFA3VHtqA6jFE3orrdml53jhxvOlrFhiRWWoqdgtzcV3HDb55f9NnqO3582a3HtIByvFAi1XjFCzoWtBuXOgjNA3lQopRtvJ8SCBK7JH1RBVVG@34dKSRShp3xXjnhDmJeth3Nqg97tCPYG7o6kTeE2g1RBoRQvSM2v23zm0ydEHqkb4Yv3Wu92TpnjVA99iyCn1@I7LEJWrns@q8hqEyi9KPrstE3cYQPHR7Mhv1YWq3piclyXa94jbI6G1cYYd7Lakd/hi0RGbRbtRzpcv@Q7CHG3d8wjup3nKOeFpqFRPA4IuiA0VPg98ZTq@QZODzNYXEXdtVSUA2s3pHQOZ2uz3O@a9B1qmpSvGNbqqfKsszBfsdqix6ML7UD3QlOXXReyfpDkC1huS@ttgg4JKtt8sBCA2xHrNfGpgd6b99piGt7CfNdrHMA9/1qXrZjseRC95W2543RJeThx@KqsDtCR2cWetaY95RmieiVerAIL7dEgmqIa3WzVU61pADURHm3pCpQC@rXpBeIpbDcqZYo@Xlmf1hNiBdgDNLyrfDIRQ536xLnlWD8tCoHciXJmJpAFxvC1E4MwuMde0gAhdwXEwjBGP8N2pM1ThO718LmKcTue5S/hnz8KeVb5xFzuUimZPFCEJ7MY4Q58qnF9oBK37XQezCliPGgp3cGMTasSLTIMZPoYzLZmcaKcQ8nMN6SazJFE7PicWxJBfI0F6QXuCoT1x0Bp8Ky7r8h1cnNaRKRKtQUafP/sdBrw@Nx5653OBJfw3qiKDc87kfVkQtOr5vU7ouykmIIovVe9n99Ijd/dgAm7eWtpI1eMgMJt4H5fFIEhsWbIs7iAIf/sSBGNjU9mFvHryJA6pzgkuW75kT1lcXluLr6TjFPRdOZHwO6NIng8lDyUGIV2vs3h@KV7wEi9jYkBZmESwPB9BniNYXorLHoK8QCAXAQNXMQjJd6zMuXYScTmE2Md7OQmDL82Yk/tSPilfrq2VcY9nKHAqcX5@0ZcKyTwk5qgXkpMxHC2PCIVfTtYIkBfyoXEkhGI5WQAUPOvkZESQ61SEn2k4z@XLuYPT70x58c5peIMPJcf38an2eRnri5zKN6VbDNyWa4tAfCeSRW9GCsI4Sy8hm4OOQF0ScuureGgqxd@MJQYtoF91alQMHY4gCBQDRAQPj5ZiV4@Nda1vH@wQuEsGPl7nFJNTrAzTEJAoIDHKkBhECNFA6zXbA8uHg6G4nOA7vvkARpns44oznh@AdkK138uJxBgnH65wA742rZc3aQzh9I1Dgube7jo@3m4d4Y7Z3f0X0IQLWI8UC369aj7hGP0qbigGf7OC5mpQBJBtfEIj6sqbajJ/DPTyF9g85AJ@GjtPSLVDCMYTC@2Q@EJzm5opsHFSenykukRHuonQBygnqjDPYLcqU3Qkx5i/dLTM3wdEh94oNZEKHH5CUUCkENLs5Kixf7x9cPSaKHfYbOwd7jQQM0ww24rdYfTGCuwghqHqfFD16RnB4RckNK@T0vJer6DhOXyC5a8z48QDwCbFNCl0ukRYX870M/A8eF4Ckig@NCgVzY5qzcGNe1d9MFEZZw5C3oq81GIoFGWaNxLSgDc7EnpytI6Sjmhpqo4Rc4Gx6Q0eisHlSdbDtw6zTHqlGfVc1KN6xC82f99TIU8vdkU@coYWrg6rHSlMfqXdVh26ECOgPqBU9S5lIiRLiFAQMr/2gfzgZ1P8sVfgoPfa0aCb8/XeQM2dVBZBe@S0@1k6bkhB4lg8HenOUytJLRI58/fMTqiO2qTK@FBmPLcrntsV5MYFLruaVsi0y/OrCUVsHnk0jzxXXDf2NDOunvhbyanlutDpnT7e4EK2EC51qMGwmXC/kG2OJ2TdU6/Jnnq9OOiJ85W7x5UyQdhJjUwMOMH4KSbMnQ6QLT5j26CTKzT7GtrY/txjqLfooZGSH3TyphgET5zSBHXag/PEJ56hepAzEBNIQzotcy6yu6RBxccXFwhZ2itPIqRr0ClMYRXQDJAWweE0UVdSJU1HTBRDgShWxShsd7xOTpDBYGZ3pg90IRCG8gOHwakEfoyPZ1RGJ70/r0aokUMCnZUiuK6aTkOCBLdrkE4D4hbrQMXT3PnVKM9WQ1TO08k0fgIGRZ1wy1wUIOhnmPdAqJd5dW69Q/XwDsNh4kSoYrmqOEHhneg9PWQFuVAIHf89ONtnpVJwOhjvlmLL@Vxw5BhvmWKlSuRn2ckCewLnR@w4okGRrZBncOoOuqCq69CJ@aOj4dCPZePT4hF/jKu@crXEZ7COEMdiaHDYAN@23VLxrdK4XusyeSRnIgsgFE9C7yv3Bm8A7A0VWzFclZ@xREEuVnYxQ0qIOqxqO/xd5vQ2b5D49Kp6Z2ir3AAMIR2zTZskEQelg5YeDmg3UgoVhhvVxmsANFcc9F8gmSPYgYuGOmcCL9ATDnWPNzgJhUigHo1GFk5GGpaRetz0Ilx5UldO9nJUypM9mYY0782fWAAir2AVojF3RxYEgWeGGZqPL4lXJXld0gcORP880@DsIMMnp948XKDhY8zszF@7nGOMIe5qh8egkdjERKioTpcJ7wwcSQDvCFTbs0NwIHqMLml4Ilx8NooUxHeBa9wWzkhGkBZBoxQNKTZyHe7SEVeGUfSC/@5j4uca9L6E2BkwFgfm/OORAgJZPsEhxNnIaQjsnxxiFMYBpeAddSkb7D8YIQ7/vBuKb@IQbxaO7oSYFyACPq8ltYuXn59Jm18L0UcpU34kbbqkFJUI9eX5YLzKAgxrFwKDQpE88irlgZ0eBufePEAqPRmkHiv8RG5fW3iR3QzQBCW@sug@Ie6FrW4eUkg8MG9UvkglttUINTPUPlxJgkYUjEA8S/1emCoEDTypwEvXCqXgOrOXxpMkFCMO/c6KHAHlO5by3nFgT6D7Zs7gXO@8inJO9qrqVZNakN4/rGsWDY2TdRXdIlzXtDxb2ZVQZb1TxhOVFYm8es7e72CAo6ubt/z@BRxQJHFyWfquk2LfdXAxRISExyiPGvPk3@RZ51CH/KEW9Ei/fn5Z6dCs7@F9VawdomgP8zumQ7w5r5Pjy2ppCJAR3DSq3uZ6nmphQagzoPRMpMsnhNnZZ2cPRbcL8pq26uMtoXt5D1PAMYSlxn7keGgI@qTaE8Ae2GeS81iAhA@LL@EOw4a4SEjmiU7qcQdGJJNiPKtNWIODA9QPMmIYi5CdoSPKj6YnmTJbijHG8WFyPg4viRjug/5fDRdk/GBBkBy0RiTGOn/NiF@JcP/browGupslNDfQu6w8/HwUipjQ34o5Tw@IW4G@4M8O@HwgrBsIRdtTBtGwBQo8zI350egUg9wfhA9uGPnIF/jwaB6kpBtAwsnoqomwQOIlzIemRVZoEjNbTGodoqjF22Sy3NSQZAjxsfNqPLXOEVk2n8ZlQO5MyjO1mkDH6JAzWeOq/PIPUmXximeap4Zv/8CGX8LK45JlMM@y8HCwt9uBUGgDS1f5yR15r9k42PWvtmLi7d6qY2KQkzHtXvZWu9ayHDByLK6tSqtD7Od4SRWPaW6dwlCGF065GXas8s0KqPeiWvaBppPqMPEBE@ENWAYAd7ug8Rr4AvmW6t7i/gGBwMmECwvRigN6uGmwsWm2gtIr4mQOL0CKyu5A4XtAmGGLXkXeVlxHHatZTJht6fAzUPBO3yxMybNYw@yBoe5B6mPoEmrmSrlRIpuhgtHJ6alc6bq5SBptRxTj4suNafcI2hBcesF3y4S28fenikkCXYNoGvqYGXgFQE/Bt2wzet8qZIWcdwvVpB23YlGHtjyoNI9YzlVKJOwdMcJROhy/MxmIKyYi/MWcq3i@wzGRXWyV9qZS8ok9LVN7MnjHnNxEwef5k2FtvJzry/s0/C0e2WworWl8zb6PeXs86P4vIPtDOz@yWTSPWroyZtKtQrcps43llVxpFedaWs8gNsTegpfohDR2dWTh6y1xYwCO415aXb1RdVbAZnyrOUMAPHaHUKVI1LKV3kDxAOOFVYbZhO7oovn1xIn@IMo09cmQLp6bYMGMGk@mMSYH2OgElxhVkJgiWIwLagKkFvw8wy3PpmmxVXB01NawR4MBnsvyUuDpKCXVwgRKoh5vJZ7BcxWeUHS6VxT6MXb@mn9/Fe4nMjV2Dt38knkLFFI1QrWArl/jpa966XHkQLDQig4M2HxVA0aEJdYUk1FuJQBoHMP43aYoq4WhQDU8kI65e4BWG8qQby72YrCKlrjU8cE9JUsstKcERALeN4WMSVdgZbOeZSTWwBeVep71GI8lq1GcuwMTER/1lnxyePsXunz3yRrdCcboxk4iZ6Lq7aqXq@zeA8Q9IKjh4M6SdMzbOYAapo1rM8GOFCC95M3CHkMbKkDhC5DUcMhmOC6FqsE3eF9ya5dQQaaj5UtvDQvCa7mqRw3@XmO//YPFrKe8NReo4k/oLcl3TKjTUpsvxNAqiVhgmigrDl6CR4g7OC4xxMc5P1DAJDcIayIZTVO@QZUXlNtcQVigzpmmISXFRqyH1nc@fUqxsfDitd@EaVTLpcY1uRpB0YdnFVRjOLjDyUiKJxlaKQS@ZypI@2oEf8WMzuaZ@70bRgkS6yjIIyQoMOjcC0fTxl0uxeT7KuXcpvcjcREPesQs78/di3VhIL7Vc5iK0P8lHyZWv@tIKZ4fLhmQQ/Yc@ctUkBsnol/q0di8jo9SYxAdDM8j1cWsA93COE/ecSiK7igR6zRCwKAdtqngumMTaRf3biBjzVENJkjNcQ1tePz@L1R4ebegC2QQfpUBYDqNgDBDZZ6yS/FEZhB9o2QS42FSNxk/tFZxlu2ln4nH1iP8PH0Y/31wSR7RoTlKNccJb18KpGiOl4gE/vaU@5nqUvF@i/rOlHeqvjP08Ov7AD38@s7S82fV17cYv6OKwBBDD5zj4JT9Gcyo8b3oXiC3UzxjGJgLRqjN99Ophxa@02UqNV3HP5vatCzTwfuX55eA5zmnEBQfCoc8n/E8VsENE@QsNx/J5Rx0Pbzt3InwLm6bqC/Gyd2EHz5@gT6pc9u2GKMpADFXyKLve9NTfsggIYaScJAnEv36YVZcpnJ1AtS2a9pfXGOhrKp@wamifA7GKLFf@wTj3hCOUNVp@yKUxkuChEqweUmGqHdguukkGDY/iaC6kI@TqZDqbG4qrxExtdhd6WlCJHakXT5LCrRuKbTW1CTpDOwa0if8eaxv7x0lPQbnjUGW3ljSG6VhKrbbJWvbBt@IzQ6FdQqPPYEK7/Ztc9jrM7woCnVAhOVbyrsmaveoXYJWj@80HOJdNavetrh4UH3ffpxlpxaDST6dn8ee@/qQbaDi3xqjLZnbAuKhYULssFpY8HSnhcCkvUCS3ge@5IY@bnEIsqc2CxVgE/kBivAaLXGQ/RGx05yMvUEsLfsaiKS4rjqwXNSsNV4FrH6QzMJlmCAhagDeHV@krCz4oPMLy9k4VFoqXbi4e8Aq80qbm1tIOoY6XciWiqa@3COF41bEadsNFAdzx9Jsqr@H9vNz5avXMO//AmtCph5XpghOhUkubo4GZQeP5g00nLEojuBUmIEDyn3TxrnhODUX8y3a46h3Kbcw96KpMsIlM6I4fZjP3uBGo7mpacWtr0BT0dEBRAQlINWKr53hehm@PwtTv6bpqJ@YT4AdUuXw3lleDLONq8xe4llK2GZbVTsOqqwK8gqVM47HG0R39VYJO5rSwxkizNQ90esVh@zRNFvsa21@KmPjEItiqx@Hms0n21iaDLQl7fsBVtjoq@1rgsU3xQTY05qRBrIZbtrsMufjULHR5GDaLBlzIkLG85HmSOzEmdajhICqTgAT59VmlZAQMKqfeBXkFFt59jo01Xgyjzbr4NseYo54k4OwGSFtw7YftJpkGMgr3yADw7MuTuhqDuEJTb9TrDvUURabVgbjUBJOVjbsQ8Wy9aTGLzGcqGbIMwHEBetkbAij2IZi@xjiNIyLkZhLmi@DV2agMasHgNMc2p9jhejrEw1IOUG3ieUdOhQU2C8gmuznceQ3x4Pp4l4LWxVTCEyTS6Qok1m0NBTPYjVMIx3GzMFmEQMcgiW@tv1q/5Haj6ECZKDsAQGDx9/RwthW0FhJRRezT@jpVEtkZFEVkAODoe4qhmoOHX38@2aEyAK9FlHozhA0Ju974Z1Ux3EaxmdnWXwZANvNHtB2N9ybgBN1EN75vVWMkU6EqMGGG5hinGW6OAbjpLx3N@EyUfwE4/ZEHA6O3p6AqRi8MgEtPbhNwKUzXim@bQBEJx0XM9wMpfM22Cltd0hCtG/i5grcUzpEexDu8bDxiBg1CQpsrAsiNy3V5pkBt43NIfPGZ@DX4KpPEJDBXZsaZCqGPsKPshmrhXzPBxLAg7hDqHDLYU8NpQHxCwUHcLIdQbm94a2lChsFDm58dQtfeog5ULbwRNwaPwMXZPizc@OrcGjzxSwR91S6HF4rAJ0tZCXj@@zjT8T8PuFN9Kf2P5HK7Nm6PFjOUGJvP64k0K6KWbOcN4HVqrTRIq7VcKfGGp6wgH4JoOfa5ZMarrXwXRtkO8NWvAUGURW73YcqQXtpyDCuTXTqaB0iG8zh0OztX2XuMEBfw1y5Am0MBy28kqZL9PKPadK6BxrJASQeoE5QzsHRS40knJYEfr7ArZ5kP@4k/L7Fs6J5CU5@ANC3I@EIKspE9ktBGPQHO5t86nTjwoumkDySBf3nIhCvKRH30c9E5S@9m@v9KV@@Oo1RfgRjIjCeTR0JQ4OXG9ridGva13zlCM1uJPldRSO7N64F8g3LmMiz6OEivxPE8ZUMzzgXvNaE@jMOLH3F/bKR1@MmF4Sizg/08INTAYH5Gl412LTs70bOcd4CEdbmFqisiMKdUTwtX7nkgt1nHm/NldsQ@dmgXPjolqB1LdwVeFsLUyY/12brXaFdTfCGgBQcgdBeydH8LkySXh5pQkNQvPB8jkOFT9Y8sKo47pQOh9zj9J@X0yOf4BXVqOe83sj5o1bj3BHk4W8Sboe26i55xxv4frIJ8tP7SWv@Cxx@Ht1IYnBzapWNxP4uOmk14ju8Fqbm34zX@BxV0oWF8bdQh2jhbxMPbPIScbPoBjTv8DcD5jlvTM3yPMHY5V1/zlEVscmTv@4AhneGL1MQxzfAGzaGO27CX64XHdRxM45LvBMa6dNc@gB/z@t3iu6Y4iozGlh5IofWC79tJcbrgTx70e9awy4WBVf6IU1wQGX2dMqTri9yaGsuX/DnlCJw2nc4RBy8/ydCuwW9C/X5qRWAoiMrYoVfJDz3bOKIXmyj7gobGa8BW2qKbEUdvCuMsBK04B26zoZmVS9stQePIw1L1HFiqC/5K9@ZyCY3Jh4e7O6fbB01j7bebh0db1FK2sjvHygeWlmylDm3eLm3IfDGnIkLcSJntgbjOI449J4lnIEft03XZdsw3VVhOn6tQEplqEYeXHPP7z0cd@qo9ipPf8KVeTp8TzuNHQ2PCA1xqxLU75ZPwPnycNxJcOaHMZAupMJdrzreZMDfCxVBmQnCnMeg/MSe1DLp/a0EIU424JBidt1b1ADFbGJyjRlGGr0DvVnNiD22HjSaHIL7EvwLEVABgHjcdTvO0Mugw30VCK@CzolqJJaVv8gV5t4bOXbIs92kbNkmrxfqkIpuGr2IuD0hVALS3GDQSuGrplc9EtOhIMgC9y3gTYFIaV4jXqEszg@yciaX/d1daRAsYv8nuq3gZxzJ/5nnvGfP6c99f9L/196zLrd5XPdbeIoVKIcAcackRxEIipRIxZxaIoei7GYgGAZBUPwk3IIPIIGQ8DS9d9rpTBrXadxcphennfZv20mamT6C/Q55grxBem673@53ASnbcaYdUSMS2D179nZ295zdc4kz29cxACweZx6yoXPCJsVa0MVHa3IN6kIVrUpFn8@cPNmaXNDf/B1bkCcYkEvrbn01RuNfrj33lc2sv7CPha/eDCeWgB2rHE2@sSqm8y/PYOf/itXIq5mLXGZF8dp0It50QgKqvYrxxPLKMmkfI@exs8sX9njVZK5/fK3dLeGMQjyZ3rUcRVsTwcZVmg/i0Ygm8tWU6B0Neket/LemDp/c1xhbgKC78WrHr9BryzjC6Wj5lTThTaCeS1TcbW39udN@Xa@tto8q7aMZ8p7BRRquOWmuqyJNu83FhXLUwNnShXV8ifxFw9yYt2in8tZlnFZGl7ND35lxyZD6O18KxpQ2Qd7GEiOLw2u5IeaEWm2bRIErVx2FeJGjshrXPDp@IbX1YASDy1JyImZf4ktbMys4NhiIis4GtD3IhufIQRlcxiahdKdGz0VSZbLQIjYh5gX@/4u1lSFBNvB4bWT1OzSyem018tpq5LXVyCKrkaXrpYk/Kh16/RKwZl1VOAPuP7UEC2prV7371uaBOnhrWz18@uD31Ld2n6p3Nx9Dyq7ae3r/7Z0HCv5vP36yraiA@XmnM0KVewVTv9Vpd@h2frVcvqUIcyRA@S31pNVTbw3anVMgnjW/1ds44S/Ffme8zqW2Tzuj2YCfg4aozDIWqwm6K@K3Jn3jhBbXh0DJPXxH1L48sY3kzdPnmyWyvaBw6MaAm9/2iAchPS56VjJGGwA/gFRA0@InWdKdxqd1YlqOikoGzvy88ggCU/joidp8vIWRPrd2DnZ2Hz9RD3f34evet9DNjtraQbcx959iFgE@2t3aebjzYJMSuAHlosK7NTJYX9SEIoLTqLRfHk8wPFgXpUL55nj1Xkql@gNtFeGr5Uk/cN9zBCSF7@7s7LRKLtozNzb3v/kOcjWdb6t0GoNcWg7VxQLhRhmNRqA2iaJdZWfqyFoWKrwh9WbqBmZXU3QHRJ/zSiPP0jux11HpB3iNiA/SFDebGTaNGiq6DrgRlXYEW1MUgWF5Ob9GKNehNro90LXhxeqx/oJFN8QxK8qRS9pLq09IMTjjTr/NYXR1AtA9a3VTteMRA@CFkCQwAN7BYMK49bKzg5ck6rZATMYo@EPCm5zwojd8eIZcIxq4SsJ9DgRyR9rE80ZTigGOWl6f59Exa@LdgWKkUBGf4NFJTrerr1xJJQ74f3ljw1dZgEzDLngMK1sLFcGzG1AD7O0nreOxrzK1LN4GgwjS6XusqfW82wJxj@6FR2iwdIpqBFTtnRr@rGtH9ZrhpECcWoQ5nCm3Habclhz8nauWg5L3IzWi3h51GhWmJP7TpQ24H2nA50EDiAr2foFuhYZjYmwJzeBYSDnjD4AiQeRTH7hRjQZHk3bHKSCyTuaF953vZGWQ80ERS8WHWmc07DDUAz6EnKEPKnJzAUIMaUqe4GsUz2HG7UHwNtxDZYgRNvB9PbhSmy086BpFE0cqRX4@odbDFhnDXVorUTzrBpvta2h8RtHzt89mefRMcohispHmfPTnjEoM6NlphG5ejhUqFs3G1BIO7pAK9o4PlF@qv3entr51/1nhg/fzjVLpOW8LrSN@vGClRH5mIZEclofRnSRtQL3SBGnKnxxiaa3PyLslrnKNDBiXEw@Y741m1eTxtWo0vU/xstx0Sry4qHGpAtmbEAlhJJlgd8uruq4yT2UaKisIgr0TGouedXVKnnCa/XoD49rjLFRhRPq4j5B6jR1WjfRrLG/X@KAHO0tK@DSeboM/q2ORC0XRT8aej9J7mfu13Hq2pKFoMZnhzOgtOq8xV7LSqzlOL51XEXRbi9HB/n11dHcWto6Ph1fCtrUQ2yu1rZBLxsXHkoXr6mg/WICWD7fPhRb6nk9GzIdkFJuhdEOc@RtLmuYvqfH9yNzR2gM0ePZiRFWD1Kpt0u@ih7gMX4pD06hA1kYTMERPDra29/dVehtv2e5CWdj3Wv022ZfiNoi4r2tPR2yHTJtd0TBNJkyQYZ50ypzNS91qFy3m2MFL2CqEB8nLeJjNwkTtBclkKtYRfLIQC4GG17wh6pFzW3eu9yC/LojnddSEUsGkWR1MxXZziQ8fdrJPm0wwbnnmjf2X3tAwM52pOOuiq@rRzEakGWE8DlrP8eU7fv7eZf74rq6HGazOtyfUYVTCb6O/fPUEKh7iS3HRncEF06KnlHRWiEqX9NiRWZ7LYX9xgjKx2OfCC1vbujDH0jTmj29YkeyIP93Ad/6ZZLZ7ct@pt3hKWbMnNBscehn3CAImE8RgtWFTBRRvzOUIo9Ew52TNMOT2WrtBranrVlI0M8FdTQZ6Azj422@Gt4dwVbDbLqyq8OVUxaeEU5MVdytag84EzG/evn3zMtzhXujihS@Km8@Q8P457g1PWxZKf@aTqhBQ7s7jvM4PCGDB0NVACjzK6AUTKgisTsyZ4vSdDiO7fdCWsxHa4kFjdp8e5PG@KFxrVk1DbYvHzieSjZ1AIn2wlrDpKK@ayOjPF1d3n4K6XVLf9VevjxcbAuF9@Pw3HCZzfzDErRIY8VGTvaKCSH7XR624MZbg4IPG068VA3NDx7Gsc7y5DX7hRhtprnFjPHiJev06cqbENkvjM1Sx1xqeX@AF1wVdmXIe2gRIWS@vNl6wjgpH1tw4GpASwbEJZbnBrXTTYJs/bdrBN@@i@iDlMYD1gFkzA7j8tWUFcs9dvFXQoSaXc5wG/IlJKnAS0OoYZQ@TvsLpaJfgDbszk17i9KMOBp4zqWuC5axlIl4urwtkOELmclqA6a7WO541adhN9j3OBjbGJL0hjQHZsjswqdc5FXWqdFJdyk6CpAYngSRlkpYECg8mb2zTkt/pvGzSJEu0OUC4nFd9r9soiv7UvYzIjlkx4RjzREL5Tv8oRZNCMU8NKn0kbKBrWSGh@obXKJICpWxAKJMFE8sLacMLCtjAkG6FvmSi4mLUAPwtjZCm2sSLNdc3XiCFjzp@e9JR21OU8XVsRE2V5BhkSW0/3lK7D9X@7t62ixpb3EQehUpphT0KxSwNo@7oJZuHCR9MxidNTtRfw7lnHc7VKPi7AeoPRhYQfw3n6goIRQOXpTq/OLpQdTi8h2ZSMkfZhky67rHpQ7E9mPTH5xfTC5reKXB6RSCBe2pexEuCe5FhkZUoHLYmB3qLw7CQyFc2tVuFoBZKoVqm4ptjIBbXoTWfnQu2lNk/YepgZdImHQTkhG0Sd4IBsjx3Jb4lDEf7JAi4SW/ZNZXJhBuGh1KxGEnOqa@bwI0dO@KuW9kVK8klVfKNoBKmMIOn6GMc0aC2rDoaqAvvQlcWHCp49N8JSztmtNF3s0yjdcTQsnNgyg0rm18lrD4fpdxPkQUnM6jceKPyusELAoO8B7t5jWncASP6joCZzUGD8QKKwNEqcAB5mUQAqXwUYzO@lcHSiykS3@JgPUabk1BLgC6mSHwtQaPdqQjWemg22gPgzjggCX5ogiBona@xMwdkE6k4abGqcEEhRRJnmlxnhv9kY@rQ2zRDAD029MdKg01v1LJdbCG8OyJ2C6Tz1oDgHkTuVPBYs9Mr4XT7SFLrVvEwhNWoEDDgDJ1Ul88FexJxks7QUouXFRltSTRw5LXkaIQtp2GBEgklgBZcUF41ASyAIghxcXiyWKC8El3QXDyoRfwEb2MNtdVajQY0Fw9qrY8I1kIcVhc0FwaN7Gu0Ubpjbxjalcziycsm8LE2OquqzrTTnoz5pNFOK2ANjWF52IyWQB95z73xPRUwWvSpCO1Bor11Rzxi6zQQ8G9/3bA@VECz2nYTpNoAIe4WFi/lxVTM11E2@xYw5oZ5dOA5xDW@j1ugdYKwp0GxByZpiGYyRKDRp5hmxeyh4VLTsaqSMZJKq6Vz@DpH7re@dM7iDkd@T@fT2Xmam1V1dlHok04W@WhtTY9FcTxoeir2pyqNJxyDoXJxFIOkBT8OjsnYpOIVR747aPNlZx5xVbWwVod0FMDpYSeEA19Ton3RBQFN4/J24INKFAc2IacWdcrGoYWqKI6VK@PQAlsUR@Hq7SB5Kq4vb1wZBwuCcThKV8aBFBgd0/TSOSCY8@90HKk544FmUZLayh@6pGFwtpxvh@G@aFFVob0gYXDgp6Fvce0Qxtym9a4lBl1pPFDoiI5HxuOVtA5HMe3cZb5grmDJbGS9sHBLqXwDa628qrrhj4/gICged836jln8IRE9dEkiCOneA4WYYvtkBCISzmZRpA/NgBBOaH@ziapZzSbdDO3t735zf/NR8/HmIxSilniPwusb1JYhdZ1ycRXj2fNtS5N0imoKVS2wGynah608ap@g2aZThCLHYqmlcwtunmYGCmuq0X1Rsd85Uw8hi4LWR3AiZNHczcD0ZKgNZlNPF07T2QDSPsF0r0ReW4eWEAzTibSEYKzklCVscflnfdZQedZ/NmbAQ1Vnm0y/Ybf3GRouWQWVKpw@G7/TGR2iLknBOC3lWUQVfJTdyDkVqlzIDXqAwZrA35RK6r52iiv2a61uG13eTo7J8W3P67Z6h0et4vBkmDr2a@KeJrN87KOTyxQqU@0cbO8/ae5hnK7tB2Q5gT9VyjvYebS9@/QAc55A1k1J3t7f391vkoL6/tO9A/QYGkpK24CCJQCTBAfo8e5bm29bMPw9LY1kgxAf5E34I6588sobNqf0e0ZmHnlWhWhSEB4yU8GilJZXY6/XGUx08Db0P6EP@DxanuCjDNSloxqTQ5oMXn9KXuDrdG5BUTtGk@GYQEkDPhMaiaxbgmF6/nMsQL6IfODbSZu@yDfKmIeGfINhJlQWDWSwWErsu459Wh24TJ7M@u2MRieOPPPnnT5A4mvT8mR8XLizPM@iV8khKQ2FCy@X4OQokXPU5fiSMoKilZ6yghjZ167VlDZ4ByiyKKFJCCxTqAC/IFZVLudlz1N2gCjJgl2V40edK8uG3oWR@DXXrDlit6as5wv1I4GYT2KBY2iEv@7Zj1JEYPI@RcYcdbQ8N2NGf3Vn@YY5Y2YnQ@9TgV13EbVHHkCDN8cZdvRCPvsCupPnLmlAEzPCM@7mAXp5G5MOU4VM4/64CgM1Hs0UWxD6YzNc0PMG/p6Ka9c2KtBkgOCyNmw6zbnsjhKNhPwxA5CYl15P3w3c2LBZglEcZog1G6ISB/GeDbEaB3FqQ9yMg/j0QwbxjjO5nJ68dbV6@zZrMzvzGVP8P0zxQkHDrmlV6KAw4LOL69OYkWwzDoHO1dAc1D6zAbndsjcXtsxF/el/Am4bl5QqUCXc8AXNXoD5sz9M3@UbuiuM0t9xD60NCpkTefJiE2a8L3wgJK6bJLakYWw/X4AtndazGF/2hwFFvJdANJ/@woGJJ5uP9LwrM376hetaULYSWDWEEfxXFEHtVRA0ubxeX@RtlA14MXv1rsGiexAgYJCbNshqGCSuyouFVZZtfJXYKis2SPkqVX76S6lTzq8YiJ8YCNprZTBjQf/HWWikmg@F4kB9hkSbmr3g1TcR/LnbBrtYHPhegJ2KNBa3@7PvhtsdlIyF/6NY4qQCNn3paY8d@H@6Ko6biTjeZxSFQuK4LTNELpcI8eknQTt4eMPLbNEi@exPLi9dTi79B0Hp4Jhf1wc3cw0aWXgLNOpBbiYVrRtsPH8wACYlpjXWMWrWnLXk8CwWgzG3AxWTLRZnbvaqzp7FZt802SHkc2awNJeE/vWIMVrjCIPEGgWfycqXGS6duV6zubYsd8jmdplZFwNzGBvD44gpjsX0rIcEjhVHyIiiltysMHvzFHHB1Vjhx2@NWif9FgZo9Qf9okQA8Qal7d7ghYcH1aiEbi6KL/wkaeiLsNaEgOS4Goqvm6hQAU0VpyKs@81yOwK22u1Jb9LFN7SayFXoGKlUQpdxJAj2Jz1fcOKJe3/idaEHNeTUAhYRxLwhtJJOYWClr1R9qOq4aqNVlkqsN14kN3SURG1rj7zhmCqrRWUBdPlEDCpU4a1ZsJqFRwP1c0LErmhr0p@3vX4nY8FjFFcvbyWQX4RcjUtViTLCY2LhyKMGyONJz8FwLjNOujE1zin6aPGTKedXceQ6SDdq1MEIIcY6wvPVqvigI9cyiEQsiEYultX8rSyPEiHaA/LsuRC38qtlrGiIWeSiiDxDG83y1jG5LSKjVsJB2Aw0zQJwhAF6Gdf1MvQOMky7aulf//TDf0hnz0slnUYxdbx@C2QGikgSYMWvB4M9/d1Cj/KJ2CqGcP9jgJtRH3XaXq@FEWrGFmogrgTMMIGI@RwIDZ1WDbqw3wyeZyxfMLpCJKxSaXNrSx28tb/7LlpD8SUCUUGoOBLBXZXO8bBTSSdfFIMRRCghCvNIKkYg3YgolOkVgpkek3ud44ylgQWj9b0/o9Giu/wBarrzugwhxOw0O/XBe0LUrbXRmonQFIzz8L0/ZcyDIWvPxiMeDNNCmPBx2AHi11eRmUi/GCK@vl/96C@pOrEoAZ4P71V6dtVJTD/l1uVClmi2UGkk9sqphgYhEfGlQ/T9nxEyn4N0640wdc3eFQ2S@G7/5G8V4cDHB5g9q6Ry8OQuRfQRIzKvBzRyifgKl@L7AeM78ugVwEZ0OHO7@AjOyeIIjYYyVnLpkuH71Y@kxQDvjfHNZEEdK05zU7GT8e/2zFJZmY6k@bXwJ87wj22kYuaahJEPqlg8H/4yWKZ2N9l1MtP3NWt1hpoW2@EP/zuO@kjHHFYPegBntPZUxa6VhDb/9d8Y/NPUteklBPPrn378SdDHaWLPpon9@ThYTdNoL6ZJbb8W2pJ@H4@MdG6aOBW/cKtxVu60Zn1NQvDzpHGfuoM9TVryQPpm0U8vWfZJSD7SSMyCn1665JNw/UDjil3s4W4lLPdp4jLX2BMWegj/SkIzYTH@m70Yp4tmPnHNJ5PF3xNyZPjQeDQyLaWScDhlYm3XVIX@omde/Lsebo29@@FVW8C41ICjAnQoNTm0h1DTNXvln4djys@ZrwlSK@JsQffIqqUitYBo0ur6MVXVal9aXas4dCDuxdSy/vkqSc1LpX6Hje4nwyOUOuj9rkeSx4ie/zB4QPzO@F2aS@C2QVxhaxtyT1CnJjfoBcePkA@iI59DWtRAD9BHIG7Q3zXT3UKFU0jeuBbG0h0wS3SNrtNRFEoURESSyFUasUIFy6mxC@FfzA7E0tUhS1c4WNJH8iMb5Fy6eX//E7MjmVEauNhDKHOX4/xnmQZSMaK3cvLYITxdMuqa880IUm6qPgISj@5/tXeLUHXJvKQFloT5h39uDrqOj7qsR9AfNHklj/8YHBMHJvEEtPZP/kgIMtmVYMtIrPkv9MT7vEMlVY4n2RXqSajmZ3@cRtKOHyTOrl4uZAnGRBlL7TxWT59s76vdpwd7Tw/wQsZ2jGhk8GRBj8Vu3pdJgHUvCSKybBXE/FUWZ608Ji8v7@VWs9T9v/oYu89oc7V0OW0N08JyP3bKVXS5BWNEU3HlEZLxiZTnSwtoHdctva3V7sgIgQC90x/jevU78EHA@GKCHT7L2cbkzybTttQtFTOeK0z9l9kt6zIm@TIBjzqcgFpF4fzVyq8p46uhDLqymuHrXS3uNY/xQy@0y08C/aopyLnZjL/wPTs7Kx5jeKrJyCt2fHRP5KNjuNLwOTAL/QFdaqLbbCA8rw2yLTovnLRfBp8K7Vb/tOWjgsy9KapE177xtRn/TSXdEQ@f9zgUx@e9J1aKbnvzs3w7D8jyh@2X@eOzo6pksGGwUTjhROR@RvpLz9efvOGxgRiM8Z7dZB12X7YHXeJ204ddOMjSQdXcQw0501/l@9Bjwxh9iTwT76eKmOYMK1IofDSgHPgIXJW2Lvam9VnDKT41xR1tFp8jYi5EygrBmM96HBQ2YMr506BSXW19Ks7ijQkZvj6gUoiGRDQzDeNYhGPOlJXi1/GFCtMQcuakoeVPu0al9XjzN5jHmiYMoIkhDHgnU6q/96z@rNH3O2crjVzpeR4dHSH0oZg10piSzx7@jKPfPe0OB76T1O/4Y1ZwKeuk9olQA9MKK77IWIU0bqBZRuHGCwYNtQNrlIlb9OY444mZKmnjnNDzdrqeDsaYG1aXxuBIe1rJQNLw4ckytbcRNSxEmG66pCPxxelCpd8doT8tDVuAMUcHMP0ZmhFioAZ3qUgMUzV3W4WvZZwAw84@cENd0fkwFfVQltXNucy/3fzrr9z8Y1gX8a0nguVNMaQ0Nu3AhtuR5cIeMddr1rxCC0orrS66/Etv98k9jVYczFZXSto0hevBLkjQWWvy2@J4gl9S@6KFgnXNUPZVsxovS14XekiNpknwCk/5mhCkPG8gHEEkplhHik3tYiDp8sZBz2Jxxc6sRk6pkVMuwtDThEY2pBgG8rTdNjTQaVsLziPAV2GNXhILld86xfhU7IpopWTqDPYcogJtYQgTinTWbsTWXrcabW1aIQRIiBEER53j1qQ7vpsKb3iVgvlm9igeSr1H8TchA94rgMBoC66yUlnGEJm8WOBVukduL@FTPZWu5Mv5Cv0r8/90Xifq/5VoYtmFrLiJ5Xzo328lsYEjGy8WVcq3cENO/S8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        86xxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print((1/2and 9or 13<<65>>65or 68)-(0and eval('\'ppp\'.bytes.class==Array and 4or(\'_\'[0]==95and-91or-93)'))^1<<65>>62);exit;"[$'#{print 187;exit}]es##print##es'$/"#wWWs {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ye{--}besizeString tnd xfmain=los1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"cl91/2 <5>6#"5"8=2860ay =+ codefn( );#6and [9]=x 3 8[]p#s
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001429 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9495 bytes)

### Verification

Run the code snippet for a TIO link.

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
159 [Agda (too slow for driver)](https://tio.run/##VczNCoJAHATw@z7FINEhWP/QA0hi9gGFUN0iYt3VlFZX3O1S9Oyb3uwyML@ByYWtvJcK5JqONU9V9@AdjrE27dtQYlTBdAteWveHINM5Eg8laMq0YFI4RJBDCfW4MzYmuASvQS/bk61EX1A8KLdO6TpHMPtc9tk92Rzi7fm6un2DyQGi@ZKFNIL3SbZOsUtP6Q8)</sup>

### Explanation

Added part:

```
;exit;"[$'#{print 187;exit}]es##print##es'$/"
```

The first `exit` exits Ruby (and probably some other languages). Then in GolfScript it calls Ruby to print and exit, while in most other languages it is just a string. The other characters are for Thutu, Pyth, Alphuck, Prelude and Incident protection.

Added some interpreters to the driver... But the link becomes too long to be included directly in an answer.

I didn't get RunR, ImageFuck and Deltaplex interpreters working on my machine. But I think I didn't change anything relevant in these languages.

Comment: I tried adding Golfscript around about answer 150 but was having trouble with the `print(` near the start of the long line. How does this deal with that section?

Comment: What is the JavaScript in the snippet doing exactly? So I know how to modify it for further answers. I see it has some TIO url and it for some reason accesses the previous answer via the stack exchange api.

Comment: @Potato44 I think it calls Ruby while parsing the whole program, before everything including the `print` being actually executed.

Comment: @Potato44 Clear (but don't delete) the arguments from the first to the Intel8080 abstraction, and generate a TIO link. Replace the url in the snippet with that link, and the snippet will extract those arguments from answer 186 and put them back.

Answer (score 11):

## 346. [Janet](https://janet-lang.org/), 15638 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8;[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl6154op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92g=1\'\0C0ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7p3qpStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKJMACQIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3i2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HbGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr7uBnP4vhxZ7aw1l/aHvMM1yPdR3z1HBkdm/G7uqmm9eygoCxtp3@ZGRYnlsRYkxlbKhb/YneN1jPHHqGk2auYbC2MbTPIFxjbHNiTVyjW4e3LGOWccb2rI7ZBQjMs08My3xjOBCWY@y@MbwYXXisY49GutV12dgxLY9C84w91eGlN@mcML3teo7e8UzbgqACY8@soT5qd3VG0ceOwRMVGYDqnFCaxZASY49txzUgB7tjuK6NnmXw1B3TfrT95OMr8dUM@1gHpMZDY3ole1Vlz03D6V5NobHPjh48uOqbZZ9KtsUeXEdJzbHtiWfveVfh59l237B0psllWbsaWABiesawlCllFoIg7IHpQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQ4pnTUZtwwkiup7ueKbVZ2emN2DewHTDdBTbHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU1IZPd8KADa6rITY3ZmO1C1PkzbGs4godExeyYmCfAAgHglvIHB4Yz0GVSm5UEjYDpzAY2hEUBLCjGIf99oT/rMnnjjiccAt67p6u0hAG3PWNfo6ZOhl2ZtCANikv/ZwLD8RgvgZABxZHOsXk0INWPetvVul2WgvQIeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPbAeoBrECjHxg1H55GY0p1A1Uec@usHwmA@G7oQ9iqw9d20dmETUMtKBPUp0h3KeO3Xf0EVCjaxBNP9t7ytyO7cAb/DAu7zc3genoHtvcZPHdJ/fjrB5Wi@y0hbCKauwcqiAWBLJTfTiBFhKtCRvqxwlTC1hl8bV4hcWBLFqG5XIsB92zxLQ8EEnNlMEB/VzLqvArMK3Ecir0lHw8jfn0HL1vDg0OpY9QitjAtTzT4J7Jsaxa4jH79rDHo3UosyLLllihyIp5VoR7mZU1yA1B55hazsOvAD@AVgZUVPhlcxzQvN1DO8W2tsN6@sgcznzoBL7D8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW4hWF7Q2A2gP9FMBLQ/MEuY4RMh6sQgUeysaGQpwPWSvP3h1g9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaSeOFcAfGcOgnGbiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdPcEMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPH44HetvwzA5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZ7CnCpQCdlg/FUZYHnOE5dndkYMikgUHZxH7n7TBhBSwmCRxxkVsC@xpCe4QhoqMjK8OObRBjCuCYnswgExg3DfsUx3niLgvZuMSB2g4O6zBcdA3HYRgXZAE3TbzKnbRd4/UEB6Q5Xj1gfgbwyJ5uDkMEqEPqHnFSeMZdyG@2iHbPsUfUa0fIi4a2PV7B94HznSGgh/aZMUd9zhj18XgIww/4G3z0A2TOdBJQSJqJ5soRgkSYrjMwASBlBWzbdIwO0d4vOqTOAoNfRLHCtPqdLEK5FxmXsmxsA892MY01GQ4rMGAYHZatK13jVEEfPnYtjlmIQzCawZjkg2jrIFwg5oRFCOmOJtM4eRTUrGuPFovGGdVeWPSBiSPM8EyfQe31gEcZU30EIhBDOcOCUXEELYbXINYECHlYrD3Wta24F0I5c0AagEKHJSGJA2nimSMDxEUbkmCN5whpZJOEWXsGTZmolZNJPuSYXCGULFwlFPfIRTx4Z4FxszvpINUwb9OiFgTjjYvCkmPoXe4neA47Ptbh58DAOPZFYhkdGPEQUYtIbjCqGkB9X4TpEEQc7A3LBTnMlZmJAiu0/L7dg8Z2ZkLZQUSCpHPYHSICkiD0msodWSCSYwManQyZyTrjMQN/EDygeT7IlGAst1@Z7A0EDgcgi3UmjjNj0zHUhDmCWF7H7vWg9b4xxgMAwUZd1pl1oHtCJWPrEbo2caLOeLGY87d1A@JYKN3tPP0a6xtAdhj5eyjOY5OfF2A8piIQKXSLSwWWDpTCInTGMyILgAlT9GxbRv@ubbjUWGznJOz6mJlr9KlrQD/rzZnRCKUcaKUWSWdd4Dx@90L4mKGwtDCYld8KPjYs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE63WQ@0kogsgAKb3ukYY89vJzaxM9OKCE77D1BwIl/JBya7A2H9Ltu80mogathyIkIBCpKI@tiX53Tktb7qA2KCZcxld85ZhrNr2UOM0yu5iy8xzgIGL8UVOIypS6AUSUxi4iErQe5odgbICz3kNiS4QG9zJteLD37R7J0Rk3ph3oiNCmxHkJXQC/FYDUOC3/A6IHk8RFj1BQ@MuuBxC2jdHS2BbIdIDrtRX1nRZWCKtwEd2Za9BCoQM4SLURZDqC6oMR4i19CHYWOk7uIu1BEy7Lk2jgMZjKHjse1Az@BMZ0YqGVVZpHX5mkwiHCuSoMkvDq0wZMRxwPdwFIQE4yHob9TFsKeCiKoDpwAmxjUN4Hk2zzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEsty0ApV3dmHAgUD4ZnyGjGTMcBNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6FzIWZEc1O@vZi5ji96ZtM3pVXWmg57yK1c41R3WQ03GAaEDOlEi3nPjySr5U8pIkKjYY0@hpPwuQkSKJEOVJ3qgHMEg8QAYzeHM6iTEhS4mppk48XolMQkOTMhlNPaJPvauYvcK/LDRjE6gX9NblfVh@JYkuEvoR5hggCJjgO6AnAGdEET2crnb1tkFcA9Qy6c7lBqFS3qqci7My7C6YV4@IRCXaHllnoXrdMghRUY1LAFGp5LTILFAwPekBCUUwUNR/LEVPUja42Ek13DPiUUTFyzBRZEkOw@FfBgAEoSMCcKH2TG9li@u3LkTCC5rtRo0NpCmgG12k1H1IJjhkYFTQ2SZpBE/E9mzDz3sG4kklBcjX3JsQGyCllqrs3Nv4ECPo/dLASIBWQULW3JAWL@en5gnk@7VirbQEyOJ2OtAaDI7nlgVYPDnvaF2E1XjC1QFFSKOVMXGi@kJ9LXGS75YoaIfzTFcFH9rPiqRGk4gBn5bXUointT3mzfonVln6IsE3AWdnXOjNqB/4s8IhIwo7csEQae91lM5EOwOHA57un30sOb3RR6otE2rsuAxtDv6kLzXMboYpH20d@9g@@BrrSUwhma7ctVDMXOlAg61k6nUtyZKTtYq61EYc8D3WzfDxoSLcUTBD2aSPY2ISrMODC7TgJz7B59eJQlIQkgOygHc@Lsi0vA4IHQJbd0dXBmEWT@VgizDJEFcJu2xAGboQNQxXA/weTp58wYr7ypSY98fMRtOdA4g8FT2rCCdjIFXBLAgqN3jIyKlBSnUtHBmdu6Kxgzw@Ril5qvIkCgdaTIf7z/YPagRWH@SQqIoiuuBLKU7XRna/HDSNYRlcYD9gavDUvIccZSnCdelBO50Fgg8r1u2Aj4AQF1Htpk0HAVFcweA@87VspGv1AlbAL0ThKtyZVQe6nwoohE8cIjroMq7bBSlgPlgFXotHbHC0MVhq5PPG8VcOTpsdeZ5dqNAaXYVxoFAbnQg6MSV0EeeS5G@WO2jf/joGuIuCZGgCkgBZu6QyZSXOxRQe5FMFneVHdDQ7KEhPyeOJzIxqSjxYIJV7rikfEbi705NL5FJ8qeahLiQ@/b2nnY/iOzP/dFMBikNqIvjyOT0cEGk40Ibseyh3bfZBqTh0mGQIYhNK4u53betazWkoycWNYZrKsB/ceJGH8NYY74hxZFSRdVVvjqjW@4ZcGm1kEUiEYUIlELx5Vf6qQ7kmpf7cO@LXRhE1HwmE7ozdAEJImmIXOjqRHzJg0mQkezjs7SA4frKtd4eBEiRBQ4stM/owoTb8@ClnsQxZWVp/KUofWJfo/gre3alaYEPb1rgiJBs78nTR3tPdh9vf37safn8wnsuUy4A4SC/NshC8oDTDXvrBu@aWCwEF4O@4WD3Ai4wAQUlmHafuA4wbhmjyByBFa2Gr0wlPrEHVtxNXi3MGYZKr6wOb0KPsfPxqH5CULS7Q1RGHL68h@M5tp@B543diqJALx9M2jIorcqrjj3U@wqlg4FhOFRUVF329nFew12WApBxZwZPwSe3QHSY0QyiPhzZoLzQIiGyBpbg4GnWamj2B6AL40qi4STlsAVTaZQuaAigKyth2YgB0xvQ1n8G9STypv0VVSvxdq1mtJwiBtEWuj/EXesZoDolYLQCUiSvvLLjO8d32Ay4NEK6CiTG5A2a5HAZjgVDBoIkzZqinh8Qh7gFzpciryAavZ7gbC5wKSWfyRXVQl4BtQzUNJBZJZxzk0a61xlIni0BPMnu0bxBpBX23I5u9eQN3xEgC3LfR1DUbOPF8bHVBAH9@A7hhgt4jVmzoTaTVXY9yYYfP1mF1rtQPGy7gQe0XXJC06QnW8HPuvp1dtbVqXd1meKNxv6YI43Z420QpN7YwK@7RrTvYQIlGqhsLMRVMPJbZcmE0BCTCnhDSinQoWCkhaanIF4SCL0oHkLLAb4VScDmsxm8HHxBPMJHUOnGdm/acZdm/FGuwdlSdwxEpMnmDnJpF@cHPRgdw5aPXBoqF5k0OzPiOI@uu3y2EhL5i6VBetDVQgg0Kx/OSFvhMjA0AkpF6jlwDmhXOG06mM8yotIPLQ0yJJxw8gEkCItWD/rAZyAxL8g2LwjPiXwWi3Ri2WcWQmsbrCS1TY9P9tsTBxcNzW60bBA9q/E4AI0KF@HrtLrYNjp8lpUnplKAEqizkTGycSoBpCtiBQYVQecrk6gLujhjDd0qI@HyC8CX2N0d4GIdg88XSSNUoqBJ7bK45yjb0heKLr2B1nyDbIWF344urVOlHwUEWFwnplkSfwaUpBN7RJGe03wLBt4LxF1hPPMGUGJoYaJes8eGdVXn4xphIlml9dx4HBi@aSXO42tra/FKvB5Pg2sLXJvo2kJXClxb5JLIhfFkdFGKNLkwtEEp0K8Zv2wEkKfJJraBKUoOb8xxQm9UKtlmWm@o/lPDZxKqAigPsSV8AJx4slZDZzIp1s9wzQbk90jZd7DtHHYcc@yT4BMQCPi7T4MsEQHUe5TmHaOKuunNFBnVHFAaDRQxE078uJE5bh6fH3dTx5fxNKZOVvUa6IfAvLzESO479mQMglsjV5GAtyUb2Uqz2q7FM/GNRKIkDSEjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSpxfBwHkvrUaXQGDsGbprVkMiQU4NEzQcsYDhNx@bwE@beTzWQqDmmT8TSw5Vo8DnTpIBFcKjTOCPBG9MCcAimhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb8wxoOZE40QzrqBlI0z6PNFf9wbgVw8yiXf8PRRgW5B0w/kXh4PhFucvEN5aTzj3F3gmB4rC1tWgnH3VOqNbE9XPpNBaZIjw2V8La5IEoyEFMIhUbEfmy52Yd0y7IkbnWlcOgGKuYPv0WACzDLYz5OGVmWOBaMzsFl8/S5AZ@F6Dw4luHQl8QWwAEC3I8MPmShKJbhYAtIF7cwwgS/SnhaalVEJCc56grn5fGH8Wg5zq1IalsGMzL5lO4YEJIEUAm1DoU1MQp35O2H2aObr2rqEH0pDGirepgEc8cHQ1om2nF1H1oPGo0h60M8hyYHRFYbAP3rAHmVeF47RVTYEWqW1nQGMEFAa5MRaWFsjP0Cx3XFX9qaQVEjggBsN5NodCJ1nrKtpWqGT71WCMGwVQOwBVBJqpRaouEGQpEJg0q/kXT4tFOjoT/bv7/K5ExpscXjFebTWyO5OQK709aYDw@qn2S60J9OyRyaQIUj/5mR4YNse1/LhZdXMDFeazdFkqNOcz9VpmRvTdey2PaSpoJuSzuNPHFcf6nwSKgjd/uwxyPrPjg5rciUSSdFPRzfmjfOQy7Pl9NyLrjnSemuwPOTyhimu50Uct4Jtcshm/IACBkz8TXJQR4F/Ef2DLoVrKL5/Cf1HuEEOZGV/FoFeQ08/Ypki4qY53Dnke56rmUv0X6mDhfFUiscFxzm256pG/qder7fgnSXvEwlZ03DunSNvvnluQUeMopTnkXAn3UKcKKACxQk31F2N5zOvcK/BwBgGK4gHIJjgKhmM7UMUn0A3QUmc73kzQJAe42IIcWhcYmMdkDXda9MW0KfGEo8txNaon8AYpqDkIqwrzJ/irlJPsWx/adLl3NMG1Z5mTzbrfDEbVSeHa20Kn3xfbwGIzXo12KC0KhrmFI@H0Qgq4QYpqJi0fn@tqOFuDJfm1AVKUhVcBbSGqZaRjqfF3eZFXHGJDD0mHh9PP8pon4P6gbvL1u8ofaOKGa6iVzUIifuianvGJBDsMBafn@4MgJ2w1HSRlFA/E6tnD7sSXwyDdsG4GoUV5O9FCHe9@ZsbDdMJNrzRjkOeFNloZK/cNbhXqrR@PUJkd10ICHrJObs4SZ9esAaMbKeyOx6aXpNdyp7dGiBJvIljXd2Hx0VNx9FnruBvZamx7YOPP2tkmhyCMNJxgavEa3EabOcE@RjkIdxfCy7ckOOZHg34tOHAxPKqMiA1pbUQQB9g8AyqLMzILxGifmFczMvSM0AhTRiIuTsbpZmRvJR7Q93zDIu3Ob7KuJrcfDnIz6ZG2W/5awsVlqEFGBBATQwDFKvs8Oj@7sGBDC3XTcR3caGmAt1R7wxADllV6ICS0cJX2EfdOPsI0yRROxegq4GS0fLTQ6OuQqMHNQNyRxbRN5wEeCZxjaUD3rSsRQm5IOYTCLdVdTyiUQgsYSShTASsshT/ZxbXqHw8K9DiU0RJIHfiTgVoaybliWW@ll0YT0g8hShxrpPCsFBbTxBTW1eT1Hocc4QrxKBIkWwIJWg0mPQGmB5EFlmzWeVL/RAX9Synj9QVRaoK2vVbU4Oqr4E3SC4EwU9ee8teNDJSuZlaXwaK9pD5G3Z5@SNwEcIiaNdYmu16gvr7tY7MceBLfpyRPyOt@cqu9Apb5w6RTy1T9GBfFDEd2ka1uB1qcbMVdDJkJTTjggUJWELM307tt1kKJ84Pqg0mI49Ekp2HRNeQ5OzigmjI1jVGNASXynhlXAZKJjCmRzaU5pG/lToqBFBv9feLYJ89FsRAm1pckMUQLqkrp1eEUOlUjKbjQqBpndi0rBO6WhlZzaPgF6YenQyvp@yZ7oBuC1FDHHhcbRV27qjdo9uSCLS64a@bkwfNm/siL8iKunJAD5pCX5Lz4l6RhWzbRm9i9WmREd1Men1LTKlcosi9dttcFRWIgNu/gueSaMCksD1rck5Wg73ZOOMC4xEwLq6kzIt@dZsRW6A7jA4epPKf//XrXaD/9doZwECBE4yhowVDN9aU1FtZWX5SfKHb8orl8@CToakTYch1G8iO7kCR9GHoWA6a1tolCYb/Ea4c@DUObRNvIBze0Mw45nzhL3guz2TZ2pkFLLOzKu6VbVc8K1rlAf2tS0TgQpBpUCJiXbwSjClfaYlo0sjGbkcq2BvFqDHzeh9MvAm/g3x6ayWaY/zd1Df9mJm83lYN0BD1tmncUOWOfjLp2tL4pB/KqYUlceelp6VeCcQBf9W3hc7lxecFdMw@jLPBc1W0@dCmnNHjtlbhWhN3LLVJ2e7yN@oIoxtycIb8viqK6R9qCh2rqWYO6faeLdGHDg3F3/Sg4JZSKUI08wqZh3p7hjLI4MNbWbiBADhOrZNKZbIrVpDH49XpUWGk9OXy8tRTucPpsWwqQOHbViU@WUYF9jey3lKrMFyZI30oad2IcyUzX7b/4FrUcOmS0hinuHBzurTm5tTHAakzGerO3HVDE5/jEawWrJp49oeNp2bHBnFgzNSirGrB0BEZMIhlBjvg5hnhrmG6RXY5mMvI2AW1EAdxKXQtZwF2x8OdoSva1HswNL4jE/e9RhqJbK@iVMc@w99K8WEAqim/Lx/R3izF6j2YkzTsDHUYx1cOBwtzgDjHeEtDPTNdg27LCXuyFFGvM1zqv9gFgtm96Gzdbc3aNYe2yw7pfhOB@g5Qgd@XN@goLU3dkmjOO@q@gQcFWxnmFaoP@/awUOorOtxW1vrE6SHf95/vy@FCDqWqt3CoQPyxLdV/ruTrJ4pzclsF0QEvB7exRpw3DLHL2JS/xLK6dKAY4Prc8pI9yJQopazwGb0VGePKypk@C54/x9CxirTB0DGekTgN0h0mKJfA4TlcxP55csvdnFv3/ZjSNbDF2woRqdyToQGDFd2vVSnTMuoHplAzmfdnUb3hxJgYSxWN/fYrA48b36BkvD9SGb8Y6/6EPK4B4AmUMNYbXzN8L6xxnMa3G5mJPjQ7xu2izCJTG4P0PUbV@Sk4nqLjeoq@NRkv1OqCdmYd3EyywTjo0nZ3ATsM@VA@VLpFUlqQz12DfjdqTFzDw31gtVwmk/EFmMjCysLLTZpUNkz7yuT3hYzJZ57zPC4upjkR5/I8iCzRnYYrWZC2SrGnyOWyYpmW4c3w/p7ctG3bww@pKWCqXRNFMZAsaUftTTV2Tdzxz4qw@dSFixMe7d6qSQs@2vi6JdAHleabKj268vNetSnh2uYI150WX2@evomsI92WC57Txjkhvsd2uFqW9GdDVLkkF2/sdVxCtdvGUOePaSF3E7yynL0R3iLT8NdkcQ2Xr9zOV9xjV5jSeAbEMrugpQyMkUGvN0j5ehdNCviPlZGmNv5WBU8No6NMd43OqghjE/iChfeFpeKIsOTZFuhXHm7nQz1liBtGfd9VHDhY3FtK5L2R3je4LYubOOV8wgI3zXC1bu5cPnVR4RtlOpBsbrxgdZOATnVizNzguRTg41kH6nUyun267Urn7@Ac6Hv09lU7Va8PsdbAHlgDY8C3h4dvqzoHtEeP2x65CXXAuj/AHWvj8cJO9ig9h/Zw@D70RNbIGaVt95bitItnXPGA1gfBneltCPAft07e6R7nHehY2WsGxgTGJdf27LEh0duqqEOc6OH3VTw0WIv@eWeQbtTzgSLB8@eFf6tu2ddtbzymR2s8nLh0o6QSHU2@TW7q8R0otPfRdvryG3vUln1P2d@eQkvgy1lM2/Q6Azwbzlu20bfbnYF5G9JtQ/cs80QJpnz463vprkgZk0n30VsemkBeZyZje6lFww/xsbeq0v3ZIz6shY4b5JVlM3R0@loa6ycdl8@GootVcEI40hv5Ge0KnXKvvJ6Y3hxoZMtSOL3LlyXQsQp3f5PESsmKjkLM2bC/eWJlKyUhHQVyyciAwKOuynZxO1uki2Wz/LYKoWgpCaPI9pMPIbe/xYdmB83IvC34L7Svhb1JSwc5azDpu9cZJp@u74KIhrfV0xa0ZTkyZQ1jlm75j1Vk1oYKnmWEZwtkrolx45pK/sZFFYqnDiXdNuHRggdU3WTlHNrQHLv8zqTeyqU4f8sS6OJX1ws5bWbLlWm/YrpGjy@BoOs2EXFkO7jhGGQQqYMr6TiDjsycC16ccVl2H5i6NGTzyEHcVWLL0t1Ay6s/HDOlz58YfR23VD8yPdyTuaRVUJNdtovoVthfneiu@dUJlGxVY0PDDHwZ0ome4Me3JfAe632z83ChIkIkfQL7Gzr5Y6H5o9f1ujgbmC7uaAodN0xMYZPjjRhbXQv0hiUxr87bhzYp5h2In3ZcGnvZ3Lo9nuGhsBm5bppWNz2aZfWfq1THVXu9bkTibDIaT1z/sRwH2jMVnYUenZC/e2YCcOk1sFY20Ife8pnqyJQrSGH@oDh3rpLGvzCHdp99UcowENpACEPhfEnDuQfD81PckONYS1oi5f2ey5440SE5vGCvoW6NLJNMy/Runs3xPNycEzyxMHzkwIMIyiO8y3c/FIJ0tJwij26X9ecnkG8Z36HlHdoTp2OgMzQrElUL/FyNnWCTMR7csNEsyllUS@vYQ@he4Bgu7TId25p4kjOxbhwVCjeOChU2LRUizYAlvrr7@Fky2hpoU/ZtUqgByt/EHc7mrpUbBq40MtMCQWw1H12MHegS97k5pAPaEXxLmm202dQhdn3fXqbvPJ3BAPLeChMw/8novtHBZcNb835iP7YtG0ajMTDK0YHBj/YvbPRYnhCTPcLD60Cf7q3ZHBLYFYMQlzb0sdGG@h3OXe8zFnHA93VPXzEU0dwg6X@h69a2Yg7bhvOKJv0i7lUq7SJCD40p6RarGwzvg5LX6XCRGOfjFvrIwoqNO7Zti9@J22bgoT6@mavAUEC3918ol3G//cK8wFL9bLGo@6d8l4jR5bYnVpXVMdr2kN9v2JNkmXxPgO6Yhqs8QlMG5FfIMQmkL/dGHlK8kYfMVSOQZE91lxbpl6sac5Dq9AO2AA10p2PjSpjvuGF3TsT@wC1sOtzCzzcOtIHwU@BYemfiG1e8Da3hqD2i20qFIVKbB0YbD/@0yWiHp0@vVyafGfItFkR2dIXn/AN2hZ26wBJPQRtJ3j5sLehRi1Q1x3QjTr1yuZw260iWaXTe6DhrZhO95nPTC@FQZuUJOVfMVUe6Ec0iKzodaF/akxa3roFAMzQkb@CAzq94N01vB9ZUlqyHTEYGLjIvrsKsFF1td0CFtZevp4fM1TEk36Qf8JLQvB@XD6XtlZIngof//XufKDAItwq5wMIIsK7bV/AB@Ylj@Y/3aYFPbdfrmdN9wBtPAaxiJ1isPCSBB@8Z6NpYVQioPWsy5LMP/ci@q1GX1DGJrNZK0pDYtWdIhnUqkb236fUS2fxsl7KN1k49oyv55g5wpUF6FBzzCqP5zyULqFHeiJs9VYUTdlrI@ds/lxH3LOAMIG/ZnjR26amM3ad7j/aP5LGrLh2ftgd4OuKaHLdgP0ErZSJTUq90J7LeybejdU3XU@4dqtLOoz0ZI6ygN1/RkOCBK3MLj5Xznr45UV3RV2pBGGp4ywXEh0ePH6XmJzFZYmfg2CMjGQ3eOTxM40mTTw6XBkdTP4De0bOnK5Pv7apqcknzfWbR6uAq7rkkp1WQjgzQRqExPuTmV24Vrjr22OgezcbGZzB4Igd33zP7wspCPtFPzT72QlZeSSjqqKwsF3LJyM5sULYNJ3yuqs8Tc4zcskMPhT9WbkdBySGrONnl0sNNK/5XpRiW8XcifFgiNXO9tXqmBD2jP0CXort/X8RUVV1F50O9B/XK8israzHCsvXhoX36HkvJhq@8SKGX5EGrksxb95EXpRGwbgVvOD3ve4KzvXIbzE0AQu/C0g5/Zlgz3ZJoLesm8aICqXFT241RvjDeY0Eq3OFzigael67xhVvqWaJDzuQtGR85kSQ7O/f2bktw4NPy5lgfP3nGnuou2hq5OWIUY@M9MJ5LRq8knLdCQ3crl1O7DoDSboTXHy/vzxV2qDtd25pNb1@Eo6OmOLSTDeEQFr5RJGNoTs1lY1WHz2s9Xb7N6La8@SEOe7YgB0dt0PiA3n3rX6hqJkMWhvCpZvjrLTUTdHCWQJc@Q7N10aCjvZA1dFBukcEjuVQbfWRMcTsKnw1eptQvHd8KN4x9xeTq4eSmsNINYbkb8rsWhp4sK2fUGwDmbwhjeTkMfmQPzwa2vKM7hrtk//FShG4qSPmGgpQj3PlNKYOToLSw6LtXi/h4dMF/LG2tR4bn5MYDu23mlpZhu4e2JNljtIl@PdzfTqE7tL2lb/tHPvj78vzOJsbSjB7rb5YHEKc5WRoETNAYTOhIxPXgxQXSNsi8htU3uRlFds/2dultKZJPbdyxvjTL@@b4/mS8GlFgiWi9/yoXX4j4HFRl@8xl9/BE3Fw6X6Ly47a45f6rRFkWzgeiEdGHR9tBo9o/VLRIjnMsPn@64I1nRr39w4ifY0ynq3RdabpKdVwaMs/1yVFuIdvN@ovTJcRafcwIpAxgw@FzpfjDedwnh9c5AWptA280DEI@0a35ROkcB34E8WBiRa1Uu2nfzgg/sssPSrpyYEo8kbBSqWRy8QMY0VOfaMs1sY62DNfphCfEvbhga/6pSggQg3Oa/jlSNHkGWp6BB0EFAuHV1iGbWk3Nl9kWfnWiAjJcknJELzIsFeTVYOvn/hHJSkW9ZGs1JlZE5h9SDe3EclunABetNEKZmHSisnUPQtaDA5aMzPazC0Z6IQiiaj4Db7ISPWpe9Y@gAkrr50/3nu4eHm0fPTtsZJqX/hHVoBCWBbkFB@E/ynZFKLtPNhhvuOVjOho9hOzokwKoT7pBuRiU7ErRagtFmxdK3MI06@eWpSh0SleRLgE/SeS5USgIj@jFYQclpvrxD2hX@IFZOvcLVcRBi5Qn1FmFZZZlPNaBd65bfvjVz6NQKH4@p4If0MGMfWO10BD7tt31c3QNdvsV5Phge@/Rs4NdFiA4bzRnZtcb1Mp5bsuYWw6AeuqZtG2pxuJ@kjjUVa0WfxAHwsTlOKvQuWqyIwztHKIF1MET2X7qDZZYJ/hAwXhYKcp//bpyGZdxB24S4sYDpOKQLTR5aihra2vsCBoJu3@w99nuAUP8d@@TN5IIQbAjPNT5Zz/uckv8gW2V4NNBzog4HtmwEKIHu4PTzvMD2Uhz6rrj1R8QIsv3dOw5NLkffjNEEOiLDNBuz8gs2hWTWUmyYsM/eORbNAsyoiYUWO/GyV60Tua47NR0TTx0jTj00FjYYmPH/SFkIE9m2/h1JPwGk06fhQDUJ5bHDfL45jti0NLkkOWk2Tohyz8iIUYixjfXoLG3DRgDmWuBBm14FfYKWiJOqFb4oXxJqsevJQlAV8glIQONRLxmXcxVjh3l3a/9M6VfZeD2wP1t3z3N3IO3X/HfeuD@Ve5@oWBDu26NbI5LFCG0IOiXgCMS0h9pH/kolMUNIcwJh0bTAr7KzBFU0ylRHaPzHPhdAnY8h5NofAaVBs0Nasw3gMDzM5xmAk0YVhQFmxTKZTJtPzemfC/YFVOGhXwhpyqApHQaACTb43085MoBJpMV6CbCqTmuvYRBf3Nzk4monBm1QpXXrLJuvciKL0NE1yGucDZA5BoM0kCSeQoIq/vJYPBJqUlMitwrrsaRcXVtGJUoHEcvfLd8QogsAcTiNDLQmPUUvx/mObPAJGcbv7gV@S7Fug9IUmFMIldSFHzTAU9sD5oPdNL5l2e46QDcC8lHQLR15/Kv55ElTGyP8vWeNT/xGnwAw@9rMvIADiqbuTqYRutWfI4gDhFERVzWfBsv2LF3bDUV3jYZNNMfLGnMFrh/WemvaLO83NvX7SAmrloxRGKxu4eWjVroAygMS2iKllXUQnJepFxuaZH8EvnZQHHQCssFZAdsClhGxzBf2WN3e2d375P9p4fXbP1RzPjVaMD365upY0lON5qhIx4t1mKV3HugHD6@9yCoiDnShQg3Bsbvl0S9qSTzySUEOT@scLVoyzC8WrrVGD/nx5mv4pvVbkKNEl3DQ818QL60YVh6QMd@rmaulZZRK5@/CaU5PCUCeoef2byGaiJ5ftlobtaPrVj8ektY0hFexOQN7ATgOnY31hVs7NcLhwULv2t5hB/AcqN9Mbu8L4rrWTQ5hUfGPftkbmzL94gERMobZAMsUpCVIOrK3rfPZfS5STiNf3eTG6eKmt6JIFzI3ETxCKij4BOeyEXmBi19W44DUGOGZlsITB5xm46B6bnQnCM3V5RICv5nEXjGCf@jntPKVKbdQYkkcjuClWY3mYcM4CUF6NAo3T2dgPr01B5zM9m0CnzfCFwHNrBfUG5JfTTYJ5MRxOvR48CgGXng3BIkBkrGQ1S5LAVcwrcOOU2h/U3Ir4E2Iv2Cy6NuPjFNygNj2jX7wNsTyTRwtI9UtclCC5JYaLIYacVFqrN5LdzYFT/Gk7hRsn@QGdHpHAG9ocugnhrTRPwsnqw0IX/0j589P40nxWVticyZ@vY9u1ftmoboF9WbOYnu@b0zMBq6jFuUy9e5BPhdBcwNbwXf6CmX5YEr0DfXaii5H3rOI3CCGJHojfQxS0wsbrRMZvSaOE5YabLmJNW53UOLpVKkUMGDAmRGKXvk4uN3QrdmLKHUoBGgr2t18fHGHLOGKstNcFMmSbaO387aAYkLrfUlBdCBIUmFwNawCYGaARjxTiLzBg5pMBziwoNMvy0Jpk8J0cSljTShUrP6HRb5Ftqi5CiWyxW/Qhe5YplB67vODmUFwF7jc4FcD9T17ZkAzUD9lYXYnJFf53gxyjfGEXnoG0IBdGIRW6WBfRQGsOaWRDsDB3@JXQv6CsgHlcqzowetUlIRWWhQpe@YXZxY5@a2QxXP/0AKdFNlIWq8yjW6jzEZmq5rcYstaEHtAXUY8QpLjUXJcPVTxfO2qao3tno/oV8LEDOHA4B/8KwVgEMbjcEWhyVhy5n9z36GH0MWE@uqetJyTlPxfKYKN7WaZ3n20fqxJK03MrW76zpoUd7r6THo5MpG7v6pMei19/rKsSiyLMspysb5efzBxlPzhVZ4Pb3MqqXXJ2O10JBfT5tiqZY@abKnTz9/23qbFKens9ficUKjj/Xu7F@Iag4V/VilzM63CtnYSRm/e8l0PX/CpqC3shP2Bq6THsN/cr/pRtw6utu9N/TdoLjIYsfH@JFjsSgqSiPehH9S91/CxRX/Rl2uy1vNt2@TDV33pjNmmubY7XbhZw9AgtSShwzyvQOcnuIr7JiepEDRNZr25vMIeh5udQ1PIcp3W@hDVhCn20a/P9nVZ@bkgff4i@fB9QyvNwdLJiSaqVRCkhpXvSstPR9jWkb7s5@sXabPn7Y2/@wbI8VYw8c@Pr59@Rjdh2r@o7W1j@7dy@XSmqZx99Mvnn5te3s7dz@df9rIb@WkzNrmn/7J2pqmbWrKWtN11Wa8cXLyuahlcqL8Zz@Kt54@/arr1rP/x9ff1lW8FeF2yorAJ@DKMhWceC/BT0UZ632v2JsYtHI1NqO/VizwP19jan2r@N@@u/865sXqmvLcgacXex0rlGLcCQ54ywZvp7F6bBOjFS5jM6VWq4Gz@N/@PaSvfwJwMGS2Cbd6PoBVmMXqUo2SXMTqBXComgb5/l9f/3oEQ84maiTGBddd1oBLzBU1casJ1wZdmwIaqpMyihLEs7yBZ9hMLd1R7@CLCS/wsAw07G14xzH8iizbv8vYQSOVSjXllgSX/ALniBRV1Y5V9Q5wA@mjjVpN2mDcEl82m7@DRoOTNKPVt2HANO6w5/8YV2yZZ/UDgRwIscLa3Zf363UoSrae3ain6PL7D3WlYkm07bsiS7OXcVA8Gs2Xj3h/YXUxU9LEdDrNO9EUCSRN5@2HvjYf41fogx2VXfVbSAJRfN/Yh8eL7eL15//rn3/vz79Lf9@j339C@31W1@wpGxDpFDpCHa67lUqnXhfrjnh@jO91aD2ZSqlSUlqXx4kN4DvNA6ZmPr6I57PxQ0YdSGXsOEmp4aJs6372@F6Pzb3r3Kce9fMDeGTyYH4pyLFANXKHVLsWDwZUf6ej1DitNyUUg2pSQy3kmxJPFWBZL7PGXagmUSuWxWZdy2v7UHWqyCtusO4yOwb6YCGgo49vfV62ehgyf6tHvWL1IFl9HudD4wXo1oVYo6E0DRoGAj92d62yVqoUKprSCj2vX6x63cswjKdu7DQWXpw6sTlBY2HTvOoXVEX4woIWzD4knhCTDPYPfAH0LbjW4I/@4Qpf8b5GPr43Rbl@rbGKuqFllfxHhV3tA/MXYHhgnXa7/abTxtFfb@sdXfX0iT7VZ7rXnrSnba8zQeM7718mIfa2scYOOBtqslRwHaduvZ7Jcst3ksPGnyTZ05gQ@0e46qqmsg0YljJwA1mMnKAq45@qCix2Dlfz7Ubj7Qb00Hpqk9hjsy75WMJDbt1tpqTLywa4q1X/f7MeOqt0cRcUrnmZSm2@qIPE8aLeSAHIFz5ImcOUW/XmJgWEefmZ@cGbTRBZpNRmY7Nm79APksAlNQHg5gKS8ZwdL9h376ZkeL8L6evrTZZMpdYlaQ3Hw4Y/UkCKZj0VFAkxSICEcH7@c/5AuYMOe7l5Wb9sbF5ebm7C/ybdL/0n@F5uXvunx/xaEWce3mSNrFZqIns5bij1Y@XYZxZNeJeVOvrIyjE46vCEeCBTCLENthFDi2zZ2IYQe/nuy/8Zf8fvvvx9lLQY/BkVIXaOPUPZQD2tzNU1uDHrscUe88sCN/6CV/RBj8d19LT4zcKlHEV5KbMKny1PqKVCUsZBrGX3WnjIW2YvISqKPMDbmaiVCmIrpc40FtsUC0Xi7r947YrH4//kpVYuxvnEBp5Nfum67uMIbiF27DHErmoZVVIv6tz@Nv8iwi8uu/7JL666hNhFmRkVIEvHZZwgQgxqISZJwOrrmyPcvIpLCxJqcae1z6Vn2xJOO@geLRx1uEpd29utlct1viqy/pRa3Mb9Dbir8L@7BsUQYu3X@PfoDf6xow7@HbzGP3b0Bv8OPPxjj9v4d/Qa/7bb@Hc0wr97r/HvsYd/z/r4d/wL2axaFdfPiQAptaxerk9FIkQ1tlU//gVeO734T7/zjW/Ea7W4FKdPMeRU22FqsgokdN149W5ciNXYurquZoaZTkZtq21wmCzjsMwgM1C7IFm0VJYxWGaWmbHMyFa74DLgLwMuM9NjmT7LWBkLIkIouLxWxkNXDx59@OsBIAf@TNxQ1VYzHQYZDVGEp2@4IXhwXbSOhQaLM/GlAfqVrMoZuWA28csXDfHly2Nlo6mVS0zGhiG3Gi@P4020kayVc6w9M9aOX7KYCwpaNaYcHyt8qgnKSuS4vGy1dp/cb7UU5LfHj@39@f/@/ij6euP/aN9@vG@PbPjf39@HBm7UU3dT0l24asCh/MdWrF7dOq4QgwuYXEzZ3DquZyV0F1LAuDT0S33gNYcIz/rasRA/S6BsfYbidfX5WfW0Su6z4BUcreo8QhCNO/wnXGfAywPB@wyu0zN00Bs6z54fhy7uUJ6fgddzBopF@A8KTPT1H@Df/H/X/@NnLMkSjWYycX65maAriX/J5Pnl@aV/rycTCf8lsQl/6AHvmOT8so5OinQOrkYi2UxeXnI/uCeSmxxgHbLZrFPaeTxg3rEwS8qW3xL/sE/I2r@O41WmzzeJHB9PM5lktR2YdsclT/2CVuKTVfp813q7oTb/9Edkvn8rSZHyuWpV3WD8Rctp1WoueCuWqtVS8LKeSJSvX/XMlloAsTqXSyarVXjZCsBm4DUEWwKwwUseoBqu3vG54PnePhm2By6Rj@EXJThbSGTosxj4haW4WBHv3En4X27e2k7euaOVMxcXoc94DF7qgler1TWdVgv9sxcXYkukPRvlPLxnShcXaqacUuNJ20k8wU9zQVYJSWUfaXXKtQzMV8sVk/8wkjYAy29uFnL1eiEH7kIJV4@vX0QNJq7HY@fBkF1MctYYX1fEKlfcoHe7eLHzyxhVO8vlkwlgrkkQgS5j@Me91XKZ@ydZrpAopcr@X20N9E8QRfgfznZkU7mN4sZdkO7wb7r0Qp5cPTdq6mXt3KjgrPFlteN/GBUPlBt37mTLQNZSpnostFr3t4@2W62aKIoozsANPYm7C/g9trETb1CV58vNBpaweRyPV6p3qXmopTyDduDHk@IwTLBSmQghmD20FgGlF7hWsMbWBI2eeBPKnJJr4AlSO2aNvy5crMvarI8X6@P8HzPZkC42ZDyc7p1OGMnmlx8avlJavEIfI7yE2NNH2zu7R2ltU2Ix7cH2Tlo7fHYvpuJrfv5OwVl8P9jdvr//DBI8fbS7fbj78d5nu8@egr/LzuZXwOf9@/wZdS15P2PPhVfOG90wdGNiGK2zyeTsNXtlmi0T6m84gULYfYe5RgtwH@vzclTh1zFd/dUr3RnTxd794FvvfvDfvfvhd9798Fvvfvi9n375vW/B78fw@w5/fufflfN4/@mX/@J33/3OD8HzP8Hvj@D3k59@@Ztf5z96/2P4/ZeI3x/7v0g8/hMA1q/89Mvv/uinX/7q9@H3r/zf96//fu0ny3/f@@bqH6b77u/eHOc7/x5@v8dhBXG/8zvcD5/X4v8Oj/er33/3G/@B//@p/4fOH777jT/Gm//yz7//p//l3Tf@o6aV/vTfvvvmd9998xvvvvntd9/8p9q73/y3aiZ6@9133/uDv/rD3/urP/wf6f/HdP@99/l/9/1//hf/y1/8b3/xh/7vJ/D7D@D6yV/8R@gbf/sHP8D/7/7B3/7RD/D/f/rXf/sHv/63v/JvyPFb3PF//6t/x@9//Wv/@W9@@9t/9ZOv/82v/@RvfusP/up//9X/8zf/81//97//1//sG@j5Wz/5qz/6lb/8xrf@8pv/8i@/8eWK@7duvH/5Hv5f/iP4vD@e7wPnfcr1oT5f/lz4/H2oMc8F2gm07l9@95u/BA38Nxh7960f4@kL@K34/7GmUpwf87f/Dzi062XGkAy44Pfr7771HSTR/wAkgv@QXt8OXxZC@Mu35y9A1t9ekuiXf/rlv/wRvcWMSp0WInC4Lmml1AaoNBvlsj9k@2sUkOSXFqGFAPycvo0caiHs28jb3v3g6@9@9E/f/eC33v3gV3DAlHLl9HZaUm@dbJPy7xEPIxbeJx5G/BzzT9E0kpT6HN7Y537g559/LrQuFDzmc/cCfD8nL34xHoTHgPygIAz98VwQu2BRt@/M@M513zfMmbHGy5dNXEIEP8w9RQLHRiAN5bNsmvIRmzK@aIH@EGm6Qc4p3skXg6cC3ub/c@dUYCmMwy/8LFngJIefzs@CO4U8ZJOahkslJJ4xLhJtcB9a@qR8c2WGJZhOU1PQe8EBOaQg6F6K1Wq1FCascXzglaNWLzFCJZWqQbkxNU@TbpUQxPQeQYGUtdQBa23UpjxhCuHVA3KkBPQ6EFVNTJVq9yHD2vQ@Q1gInMC@fFmrl2rTOoJ7y@mRmqbuEU4IrJaa1t/Ce41gQjohdv8toFKqpVL1EmaIheTVk27xSspT4ajsKZby6wCeuIN96y5jH4lqSWxxKREJxmPjPTWPjREhOoQfpzb84tB/4KTfBhF8jbLyc2E8fIsE0i0uo2IEgCtJsiwz@OGa8ha7C8FTDipF2cIjxSGkqEVQCwg9GE7/pIQU1W@KXiD/WG3jgy8EhoVZX18XYnUxK@7LRDpFYc5Jhbbz4w43VEAqTCyURfQ26GxDgAukr1L@63FcNYozDph9lOK/u3c32EdQTHrO/QQmpbJ2zo5xKJuplKgB/LqdEl6AJiJAOyVAF4I8rZGykxLSacbkWgzD2P7@vo8EebyoCSlo5lpWxXdcK5lMJjFIIctpOZ32nzI9yUP2HTKF@k95HYlLn7hlmpargsJUZejFotqNCoower59@xZqhbYMVfZAR2X@7iEtV6JA8ODWDobDWXAGRsuVBa6fM7WQYyxBk6BwJVlSYAm2kRT4RnOORHAl4lqpFKd4QH05sRFsJiuo1BxwAjRWR0SDiyuNpXwyCNzZZzv7jx/vPjkaN5tMMOiTvUZr7Ngdw3UTGLb95D4/ZKCVC8lYo4GgjyoaMhhht5IhZrx3/2DvsMJ4of0qSBBiVVo09ItZVoXYePx8M@ZvphHxc1S2eIj3yrxsCa2chaSxuhDrGKhZ4GpwlTZRVIXHbv@ePQXVPy2KabWA6lySpn2Z8DV7wtBYIresAH0Kjx7Im5tEAaF@LtHMPDqhtgpCve5vQ2OqUD/cPYIER/tM1TKyUP@cTWXMULoU6sPa0LD63mAd93OJxxkxUqb1RiaNf1o2C3c1V0ir@WJzbW14LmGex1Rt57gx7xJezyUsxlfgYsJXBPYV8IIL8sDddszf6ri3X/X3m6FZogTfdCaqeehmSeEYKpqDE8bzCxCF1r24ziHE1r74wmP1OqjU0t4DIQbcYsCCLVeS2ZUHMlVzd@IYFNpnrGt@ZuJ3xuSu6Y6H@gy6DlAjdnl52QNIew@YVtfolafo4v2yQz5tcF9OdSFmVSq1t2quKGgnlcrbrKYJ4CFsKLinaw0aAC2Sbyj8r@pCJtlsSQFOpYoiPLLZrIBTw4JQMQRG@x/eZmo1ibfBbE6l7Q84RaDo05oWXn7c6UfzuNkMj4shEMD6nsMyQViRh/lvBYHegGi44Ys@lFr1O2fmzp0szltkc5lwgoJKzC6hbtazuSxSXPj/r8WLll42x/VsRt1UxuDUwZnbVHRwtsGZ31Ta4DTBWd5UTHBO6lk1s6lM6gITNrmFQoYGEGqiZ0zRICr3E@uuMezJeG6mJlIGmrjpW/ytBwnr3VrX7tBXjatd2cSvS@O5RZ4glxOrtoW2s2p4ip5OerJE8lzo187odKVg1PoymmNwLH0odOW23Z3Jrjcb4gmUoe3U4iAXxoOAOXQDBBKc99rKZnOVBmvKY3u8JWj5YqqhZmAkwZ9aSmvpNWOrWKx05c7Q0J2tfCVfSnfxcIu/HrWVz1T68uePHz30vPGBQSdetnJlSIAGjNDUyFapks83Gw1RTDUomyZ@rJXzKWltDTq3oXclePZsy3MlrdSExF3TqdXi8a2sqklqJZspXQpzwiHNsYR1AZOmsGRppPu5zwoqlm0B16mk9bR5TlSo9Hq9y43z1PxF0M8l/gb0uZT0dPs8fK1KkXgVNklL5jwQfPQekPvcX4iriFq@JFYb1fl7sSBWm5fC3ZHRNXU86HKcOb@eqgDcmUONQUbHTLisOLbtVdpGz3aMecSsWggicoSuR8iJl2F2xxnM8fx6doVIpOn5dSi5vHgZpgrQEi4vge6c2NAvuPXJOu0HbajlXHMXWFGjuRnYpcS6ib14oev1OlTyea6o5fK5vJYtFPJFDYaccq6QL0E3yxQyeU0DALlyqVy8hBYtxHRdqteyWlbQNEnLSllVUrP4f4tDw//3j6/Bv4Z3SJXVhCM07vAExjIYfy32CA@JezY7svEzIX12z@isiLEz0Gnn7I5ju@7fI8493TrhQfdNblExDHqo47eS3JHpDVbEeDYeoV0Iw/lHg7A7agOCyJp4hHtwc4a2vSxCkT17uqKUj0MbxkAMbsQYoh/sffzwKPI82t3eeSgU2L39J/evPPJ@pDx7tPvgKHwt8tAgaT4E8bXdR4@uvvqP3P6zg97EdvAnPNh/lpvfQi88mCnk4FqMFHoTEP@GryTt4Qz/GssXA4cq4Hb@O6Cx3vGd@cLcmUHnc37q1HTD7eX8AHJFOAqOouoMuV7bYB1u/gNVaDLN5QvYarEsCGNm2WesmGFdezjU8cPPvTXwHOh4rM5AKXNI3y3HrM9sZ9g9M7vGmvAYT/CVVfzILiIhPAQgo0mH7OCAhIGGHrv4SWZcUmoPJwab4OfQV3jCA73Q6Zj9AYyHZ3YQQWjrOoPfh16Q3ohe3s0eHs@D/K6FDK9HF2KCKD7UPf1urAQM3G2O65lK5c4d9akjlrOi2zd2p9Bg2TPoQLozS5dETxYfMLkV6@NSw7Cg5nP2uK7XQTdogCQNw@hWTjPqpUz@r3/7x3/3J79e1vo19Th@nNnJPH6UrwBzBNmSkfjoi5gyKRtauZQvlbNaKV0ql3J5tZDPp1UtDXpasQyiekYtqYVSvqymS7kyiAS5MoTmy0VfQFUCiVTZqABYq4Nffd0kfUUegGLC1xDZm4SeZDE9fJ8w0YA0ooCqoUdnlDfMGoxmTM2wbJEBRJ11WOzBg53MgweieA9fcO/ETkYUu/iSL2UyxXuiaFDITgnFG9HmaUpoP0v0@Esmc29HFCccAJqeFsUBvuwWcJJLFE182dl@8ADz6eGLhukh2gkP4S/D4KUI0Sx8AbmZALwOoUG0bZ5PjhDdxRfMEkMe8JAdCBPFjwN0MOSAR@MAHgYl3d4WxT3@sr2NITtU7DxH9FN82aZLFB14gbYvin1w9B3odaLYBif2AFHsgKsz08EPv7CL1oktTxfFGScPEkgUpxRb75yIYivwx2w@87HJI3Ur9KLyUt@llzL@iaIWII3RsuFLVhRz4UsOyvbw4Wf6wOsafX7NHP7sQEkfPszq5nSy@6D98cftfr/tzLZ3Pz7AoJ2dhyAazCZOu9/2E7ZbcNmQauehpp@MZlcvKPVeq1XRh0uDPm21crp1Jag1axmIIaR6DZj5Vx8zGrV2IGjnYeuuvmw9lwC2sPOP4NnG694Invf0Ng8KLgqi57TdFqvY/FFup@/eQ0@kT9CnR3rHsav4Pq2tMRZPxNOzRiHTrFIAG4H8nale0gfvE3jXcTImeT5rTGuZZm1aK2p8L1AvIR5PtbwpptdGW2o5X1nTt1Qtl5pW0EKC3YuzuKRusYR6Z@MNSzxJbmkgi4vHW1uS2FCbW5paqhSKLzYmopis4H0rW6xAxEw8wxjeko1ic6uYjyQpFlO6olWKxWT1EujhwWjexkmSViJxZugnySSiiyo7FIHKymZUTrPaS0zT0xrHi82S1WlNrXKDnCxzDVYXrT9POp7tcIh9ADfdylRwETwhquWSCPkrSiKZRF2alGVFmG84fP7Vo5Ojo8@BEzKh7k8lPOUfq676rx8/3JH39oM3tNosP0D9x3bkHWRXCyHcqHDgdQSagPwQhk/QqgI/PIfm2EN5d9oxxqhEBQGBLU7Zt6AoHz1cgHM4sM94zniMv0pmuKyOwdCotdlleq0OLr3LEoQV05NnNHC36vVaqzaik@5QxCDVp4wsPs/B7Lkc99C4ACU/x7NZfkCrlrmstmvT2BTgtGpMUl@O7O5LLdWpdtGW9b3aPUxcbcGzXTVqhuPYjhgTq70tq8bYxHL1nvHUcNBsxt7@OogReGAr0WNGcp0d72LsHdQXLqW6w6w5Zk8mowQI5O3kolfkFUmT@GpQ5HM6QYh7JC6rvRpLvEhWX8Ors84SXflecitX7SbusVYSfDIvey97TGOFXJU@MptASNCJiDZYZj1Zq38Kkg8HfFKpACJ@HZ8ATMwJwJpdCtCTY/Oy2qkNWUJiU5Yk8uSq/VoDU1/gbVMSxaYkNS6aQl2Sngt16KfVWUyvuZM2fQCBZdqqlilUp@CnFnPVAVSs/mJadWrjiWNUh/Dqz6vxg5J6FcgJVAMwby4S737p68lNKV/jflUCdTEEYaMlt2rTqoUm1aBJ1LI1CEg1cpk06NBwK6ZhmNcKabWQzqZzaamIvjDGp/Np8AS9BkSKxDAhMiamM9OMrKZVQ00nMi/N7stk@iQBsgqRjCXTnr1rTUYMfKCSsFXSKzx1lkxpG0MGtWAzfVOiZgqcoooFA5oP2NhMDxDUgaEPKUUyKbHsRmK4nsA460eT8W6jWansTsdfhaCE9HqrkCpmUm@SyWpiLVlzjddCvSrUkatQqcdr0Gb9KUfmTkYNqGNwqUWt0mi0sYjFTDqbyULpzNZFf1Osi810Zq2gQhVdMhKPGOcY0Vk4FHLmfuMWyttDA6pOLWtVQaYpsWxJk8pKfiOf4dNyPKUw9tkaUpIljsXgUHAiHi9q8XgyXsUFgTXRnwEGXkZ8LA5MNX5H3RJB/hIrYlnDCHOWSOc@MwF2IIFdCjj9wHJlIXYuXJ5fboIyrND2SRAY2Rq5JLl@V4hVGAMx8Ng3Q6SsMfahuzJTm/UX/HmMW88BrkC2T0ECpd1ShokKGPsMj7hvsTggpjujhqZlmw2tCAMZMMcgKqjhVVwDieHedrkOFHbPAb/NVB1Ph33KZjM9JQWT8ncY66fWBSpz7Op653Ztu3@wHewF297Bed5jkLDFalyMncdj8Uv4E2J36Uiaxo@ksVjkUBqf5/@F@N1YPB7HCXUg1NsY8Qi2cx7Mf1XwU1wJvcI5QqOZfPvEHJ6XshKflgAWdXkZW1dwtdNfqMjmCsky1VRwSOjTlxo0kphlBx6gGeEMEgxe@TxOXseUl2P3C62Ufby3b913HhiMnxkq5VpiPcYyqoRHb6oV3zcvttZOVGgjWTF7ko6xuzHafC6WS5qocY9qjJ1IcbXCzxmND8svii9KLx4/23@2/0CIHa9drNm4TsHCvXRvrU@@ChHj2VycseNabFrLVf2ddPW6pG5qaAmsyCrA/ntqQcpc1Hkzr1NAQYOQd7/0/dx0swTvWkaFd03Lp7R6Xd3QWDI2fvfl76NRl/Pdz7YfsTjObv/dn/xIK/7dn/xr2p0Wv6QZby1bjEFMdKqFYuz8fHx@fgkXD8vHmjGOVK6YBDdffVFjdUXVspZlVVlF0fWNYiqn3bWqih9XLarJmCvF/HWkYj7mXvhBWqYEQcFCD3mJBayS2O6BmdfUu5tbUJytbE6rrmE7UsOjjSz82zTcckyIlR6/vGAMXjr1br9vauRSFFZ5K7HNt9Ime4urLG@lNfayVsfVehUPRAarEBt4VAxX4uL1lLIRZ6AXsXrjsnrZTNFCBiiQLwxjwzq@0guO1/Ccw6LXhgV/xoZLf5go8HDhNXgzNl65YmIjqSjdbmg6bNNg@To0iw0FcNsIliL4nyQdJ9/90m9qWuHv/uTXLloXrc810CTL5YKqxX72s82JNXGNbv1nkPAGcx2BNkjrOGhXAx2hFsm41UfTTxU65A4osBMLxWYeP9ApUYtEocPsW0aXdErhFAUlqskWtxjXTVC0DTzNnyaxmyw0JauCEIqnJFY7/U6aYLANNAsIXV04F76CQTAasxpwYeErc1DgMYLx1@603OHEGdOpkASlU5tpdgeSQA5fQWN8a2SFwGflErA/ZeN6Uo6yS1QjoYqNDNdF034wCglfgSS@ydThjI11NJiBMU0Lxg4ZoxCeFNBtQN5NyHvIE7TIN0Gl5xHSjGPHE1kgegtfAWmCqGCCkMHMTYhQBb70FSAAlCHhAzabbJNlk@zcTKWqc7uBl7gzHi0b6sFhfQGTIbQuGocIElcxHniByI8f6cN24dcwyHcRzwAIh8FX1WugNGByekOpjaxpvDcogEWWqxJUNHbnzhyrWs3sJhmVCOGfmGOc7qJ6sJbjCsACheujbkVMM7TIWA18w2YHFE8RutDqJG6KsRpJykR8vRQE@H/vRost8kpVUUAVC@DXF@8VHSAZJEay8zrssM0aU7VikoXIdwD3DiFFZ6ZDLfJ4@pGsfR4EXgKGP4sFn8AAFnUUnUL02@1Vaw0MRtEJfn8AbXZxZuBbWeBWuZDV7XlB6jAVFMUcUuye6YCGQ8v9gUHARFZNYrK5AUXCg/a7azncKa7lk/igVBibwVNHw3Z@PmtkkKdjQ4W6Y9siS3hkqQe39EOLAB7lGxHjaE@sM/xejV83lDiKkUsGxLDlI8Zk2Y8@9Etpcb297YAaHNAmzYy@zDqjLtPKLEENjYydWSG4JCUihNsgLiON20NjBCgdGgad0nIritIHaWvSJotvj01oV4MHJow3lqv431RWzswTUzlCe/uS3cPDXNx@RgwFNOx@fGnft642tO0TNjRPDD4znFiwPuIyUBhA5k0DZec/IGwF94xo2TTLQHCax4JfER5F7iylI2nXErPk9WdWXUu0sEYvaPAxHfxe8qluRehL14Xg68juzA3sF5EVHniXQ5Zr@JZLanG0SRCa5BF8S0w1MgIk44rDOAEaa2DBCJ3C2DFOGWq7Ao4xwDQ7gS0Q7MVQ2q/QAEB9D3oWGjb0nApasAFMnG6iA13PZ/AW@4hlNQEjcvNSvikogIFVX1uEDmGQFMvhel2oGJmm2ZGvQO8cdSEMbSf4zQ/TB60b3WR0ct682ZoPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wd2J6p6GsQWAAMl2CylhBTADYlJkUOOkx/NTlv7QLxkgq7DinNEIJPaoBCokLwQXUW@bCMAAH3dJdbH/fNHp6dnclki3PimLLh4sdWXPxKvDLumyBS24pnjMb@Zy1N/JyxD3fukvg3luTxYLw1Rdm1Vr4z409B6Lk1f@dNIt5z4zg4nuK3RPojstuFBrNcalAPTPoOUSfhbwTi7U9rps@D9lfB9ieV4pcIhDEEM03P0p00AEu3Oyfp3lm36gecUocE4FCLRuCJFnKd4GXkBi5z3Atj2B7y0TCoPTyhNVSAJPI53XnWvIRBzFnw6r@PzSkksowztu04@ixB4UmMjQ04MSOxh81g2KcQcMIww865uVZz2pg1F5JPw@QwqIU7CBw0yiWc3wyU2@7F8CkPn0L4lIdP55kG2TamTS6SodclFgdbPdpyDGIimFkQ55LbuZ2HEGSQvpnKQWDM2YLfJfw6NUod0Ju/QT3WgoYBbWIMBDcSSuPFceO4abnG2UYzpfShsYtECKhxAN1oEk3PuqEbqT88HY5td8HLQhOeMCr5eKNXZ@C3Bt5WsIxhBVHD4PQy0epif@RvdeACgV9ggIByGASiaLDtJcxkNbQVTYHQcBrinMYcsYaPTJOkLz/I9wNxiZOeEzYKqBkBhP5hkQBNCGFBz@Gf1gq4w3PHhjhBXIm@BjRC61/xZhwoeaWrcF5TpUqKYCVJAZpAdhRXa1eLEoRDVTSuBEWKeenXfxT9tQ9Gvwf9Yjn21GD5gFEVol0FtxmCCOF3F6Iqq9ci9QoYKBv60HBg5Nrl8qk/WkM2G0qgZvB8sAjuGX4vPBGp/E6S1w8daRQtsRI2hVmtBkWc1Xi35P0iICkneJjM9ZPNgobgp@cMBGBkliYz/GTTaLJprcYZB5uuSHYWQXJKSE55Eh57ugLJpp8MtKe9YHjB6mmCdIr7IEWAp/JhFMSgscjwo@G4CP4KLRPi4qmf55znUCvw2xCK2NjOOs2luTciSEeY1hUA2BCvAejyr3RWhKsMT5XCt5BHcVIGPIq/@c2A8wpoYMSCq9x6byJsZKQDg8AvpmgcgL4rphqCqNLEMP5l@E9MB57BT73umVmMqS56ZtJX/v5RPJtI2UgHjUgfaiaHDBk1mWeWb/YyKnPE8IPWAxukuvaZzRJLhG3wVyZ@UqU9tNvKSMfNLPjtPv979uNZMtAfcFGF3R3bnu7ZuVyFK00mNbtl@XOdwexbNn7yI2LBG2S9rm24VtyDSu3Yfct0jTRD44onhq92GP4nBYSonOw7bVcQ/ClNrsYiaN6uUNRttfBrwq1WAncOJivhfmjaSIjNMx4XUP8FVyQ9sCcf6P44YbdfGR0veTtMNEfvJzsyOyeJ/bEfiNOv2wx4WAfkfwgdgATDXHuuOZKpaxSl216CvnsxsEd2H6S@iSsLmPoK@L05bERIH48JlzTTUaWtRD5KQL0k0UnrST/ppx@clH2qJfRkmF5bBLBAjDRzrtIYKessya61MjueLMjv8MPxPYzie3gzvqSFX8WZq@Y1HvhhWWcTcwgQcY5G9nY0sOjAt7rX0FlAJfRGuYoneG8Uu7RZrIuYbkPUbT@63IP2kQ7fXHgLEf9sFf1vrsAg@e77Vp@On1g/nAG/GeEmyAR9pckNVkcTEH0vibznenZh077/nnlBXPxA3gMUIUCMJcZloZVe6JhjULvdcLo4AHxLm8f9WdfaPW3aqvHAJTg5p2l2oq2uovutrjHUZ0Y34cdMR@AGJT4AhY341fsVHBkdMT2b63oJGLuSYSgM40h0Hqmyosno6dNkcnWz4lHMsPXQTDlhuLeafhh@jTXjFF@Nz1aDHhCPx3A69tTE6c/xbDzjhuCH/Fs9Ph/l4w@vSbTbcDtBgA589FTT82yTN7HPg0RYpPcYEcK48mKR0U5zABFtEV2vww8j0e0lhcqNJKoFtSwsfgJleY2bN9V4pFUEbZIvM71fk7yt0b13m4s0NQ5szsJ2PmwIuQYZN3R0OokoRO5zY43Z1jWegH40T2etGFVaSxhqmJI4nWeSuk3yRVJAzXgPnjjh9Bk8EWDf8Fq8QQVlwzkt/6t3jEJG@jgitfg@IKQDlAgVOcl9NCKxhMAN0c8vwzw7K/PsXMuzs5Bn2AMWs4xEEjoLWfq1gNVzUxUMjZ63gjtjEOrO8LiJbcNl2bqDsxXncTNeMdMsfhqvAEOOG/HKbgKYcrwbr9wnhxuvHJLjJF75FBzzvhW/iFeCboERHHglx13091k4vnfilZ1E8lLw9BPDDfKV45WwTiHOFn8ligApsNwgNeISm2X7xfQcAwY2EirTDFuMm0b1ieZh0vTLwD//qBF97gQDcY5zgyKzFFMXBo3IiMHzgWEjMKe/pCdX/NF8d/8BbYgKo2A2KdDxomkIPIjhsfgiM@KIYSitaMATEES@WVmOEYuMZO@Jjp87tFCq5MX8iXoyyQPdBIU3IHJzngl9ycpPH9TXIghege@HJyZehec1dILsCCNck00uQQuJ@jJ@Q6Gwrhdx8Ws/WkM0170YCbCVgii8lghshKeDDEeLc5jZ2B4vNhIKxS33ZjQNTcrxTomt90oy4gp@z1wRTN5@yZAxRDt/8qbiRNIhagssCAMbmSbvZeG4QLwYg@a8LiKp8s4HKER4DvRwo3NCXwm77zspHmc3aRorVg1DQVqeJXGuRTYJiWU0hDXRPZ57qLzuonmsD1Nfg5RTnGtJIIBIyjAXzl/tD5DfbS6/BwJ1QIQrGSwTrJcPpdfF6xtH2SuYD@fZXq9ADEyz@8mlwlGYw5zkoB1EJPOb2to1ER@3fHAhn2caQr8i7QdkC3WCW@h2VbfgsFBKcE4XPU808DzRVhPqukQyPJUDoUXGnHw4vOAhpvOi3YwrL/iyKsYQmt/Whx9cwc5iBUcrD@FRAZwrJOe93JlYtMtl3reBbXMfZKlqhXFGTsulYTXPPYHd09JtuGwLHvutg/v7Tx59DQbdYrGY9Mfo2Rw/7LU41xqO4xwy7a4Ox4MlaouWxk/54GI3Tse7A9vx1o4t8Rov4cwahAEdcgman9/Hkz4vi/DzK30X0vG4EYr6sE7m3UBf4Eoo6ug4ZJs@XT0giOElNnQfSCDeAr3TpK0l6aM1rZalj4xWi4avVgs3L7Va/iiGVROsiCd/FltTJq5DX83lX1w6EwSy9MDu77PnD7eP2NHDXfbg2c6n7Gv7z9jz7SdHeMj/6bN7j/Z2GPx2nxzuMmFh2yV@nQ4VSqDrfaNj4CdHmZbJ5BhB3rHHM853EjtJ7n@oj9hDu2PgMtWmq4/uDviLbBn/T3HXutXGspx/M0/RlrDRwOiGDcYWwhYgbJ1g8OFiby/A2kIawewtJG2NAMk2e53kR14g@Z9HyKvkHfIrT5HUV9U90yMExsdZ63gto5np7urq6urqW12Ga1KqStvRMc4wA45GeBEMoW/B4fNoG4vFTYvNBGEMoCjvKe1pL7Dnvei1gnZAeR3sffuBHxrLMtUJqAdJ3hpDZ08WSYiUx6pDHAETGljXVLxB@XF3Q2Aaon8FEiOHhNZr5ZQmXPTvhyl4UN17t6/gL2Jjd2ezdlDb3dlXW7t79Pr@U23nDdGztn@wV1s/RBJnfLe7WduqbVT4gyBQyCk4cvjtMhzei0IO2Zkqzd9x853rU/dHb8lTb6zg1XWDDSZDNXfZhfQJGp3gi9@aKzmXIZYvMNLkqwKVma3svflAc77y/8ANp7kKZv2D1GHI0RtnC2qVa6PBskbjreQYD42ZbNHl@4iLsUIAF7/EDh4y/OwpA5yVeFqBr1Ib0FHB2bf4geCxbEBTRY8INkAZhZWy4sBLc3PeKoNco9qanR5cd0ptokSoX1D0tVE1KTlMMa0rA6AweKh1cR5ULEUfiO/pw6KudjiQDOpp9EEyqGfyAUvRGnRH1JLOcTncvYR4Vsvy4beL/hZfC6vn0Yf1Bu9iVzRO0m/cpQ0VBa6DV4wOh9eSUx4OAdoIm0HARULOj9BTnY4MDF@CHpJMlKtE1m2jnCkSNm1cNWi1N4kljFTiBugJNdrDUGXKbk4dQDnI7wYS2Oys0@iKClSsusO8p1bggKi8ppcPUUAwNiHp95gBEYwwiUdUblOvCv2HlqOS67dqbGgdSQ7KaVTQvofA@i0E/h4wBCib2Ok0eaZiG1aA6bU1K2fCHnEkzm3/tPMTO7cum36igNbayvwWfPniaiJ7iX2S0VNk7KiLvvgDWlbyVWa7N6AxzmKVQyhBCjbPe/1hIH2YSbaAb5x4mqPcmNiotl8NcXVtoMNkjd1e16r0lLj4jlpPiSkfUitzvNydR@Irjq1LnE@TsOjdAZ3Gae/Kt@7OPFwiXfs4fqGFMN@V4/BzPGRMZP3pxLLjT4WQnCvltc314@yfv3qIyyliQcLiGqVD/CfGRF00PPiejxUWB1h36ZFm4qmFl6corXXwtLTEKDfAaB94HtC@7nW9FKWJuvHt7zCymfzOH799K0upLCSTjqUcnmdi6eapI1Olx2VOlFYBsWQnIUuyPmO@eAwzktevYViDXoBHnS7kCPbtE9HKtAgxrTu9bJNk0UFjdXdH8F21xhoVccRtGMzY/ZH/nFkvL6y5@VihRFnkzBgR7RnIRde11FJ4vroFbvN@cCS/Hw5u5V7sZHr4IWib90L7IdyyC3fDkmnJgvVwsH/eA1Ymt78LLLXduxuwTJK3oUWcHjGnN5uOtGnvr/HXW33HY4/AYO7FCUoE1KrtsstX1MZTdkYKuDaYeEG0f7BZ3dtTKdmfUFmSe9gytLQYBOxH6n2sbRt0WdjlokWT7d5aFk/mS0Kjzfy7bzBPJd4dokKvQTxNj0hYxOFv2sFIpJ6eWXgJwdr3LBAN5ZLYfTUyKDzSgG9oD0jIxp1mNdCZ2sy0TD5BaCuBa7p5sja2dfhZw1rmboRiHYxtQLZOUOMMliXT@@@jrI9fmnpkgQXvQ2hwi1bSNN/QPmGfKu5Txlwu2YP3dIvpUijZywI7bWgHxa9CcoX98wzFjCSLcFkLW2JdL441arI@njXLHFZIxDTQgKanThSNZkowIp6/rNod6saTXiY5BdEiE8E5X9tcQcVPbvQUxtSI5slytCC3x9osY3NksDzB6ayGXbo702PoQi9PiofJqkja3ltV9v@nKpklEjUZmk9tjEkkyMtLS0@/B3uyFaZ49mdhyxwyKT@HF33a38cgw3HIx/vEubUdz6THDHAP6US13gyYiYK01JkypyTazpORjR/hIudChAz8xiPe6WStrhpN4DYdusxINnTOcqsN1hCOGiqj5hb1b@6vDgL5u/U9@vH6ZLAhE1QHb6CV/643CP3YKs9y7mJ9gjls8ps/GHQ5m9gzXQBKhs2Y7jW2Y2s7UXiVViGR79vslrS1dZKo3XrmrIEr4ePFHEIc43SvNHm8ly2W7KZu1barap79SLYTZ5GpQcq1ZM@joHsfAiyD@VwC0wfb8D0OX9J/wsEzIIlMbM2XYdq438WNKUKr5iOOG6TVQrVsLU72fjtsNrrwCeKlHocq5T2hgnwKW93dcqedrBdKifKEXNjvZqiUl8rmUlyUvuFAF5CSIKQ38d2asGCpYTQlYV5z1oN@FC62/JGcnrHmZCNfXCksv3C4dV1v6F0cvTjx5pvllKLJt9G9CC8H163fz3rnV23VUf3fTkfN8Zc/lFp6pp5SXYtPxJlvcbmcZ/@pz@nvinpRYM7VCL5ix8QIuZuTWKRKzal4H156pCQiCW@aX8JCYoJL1fyF4UKY2A3LF0fLJ@VuuVC6OOqelGDkN1woDxeKCxl8eEKzKMkYuZk/Gp5gTrVPXf3ulYLLTI5@qU1DFJuG0Jd3jUHQ267svEmcxmEBgCMwrevNB@oS3ngG2mywPcl1/euMPibzFDjWwQLJmWGroCJs5fk8GccxrYAwo17xaDUbjvjv2HVmCrnL/rDHKcYvIlhLfQu@OTPGjKnAJwqU5Sgw3hNhX0Bw4jwZXAzJ17FoUWeLslwrwnbStUAcoSSLw9RxKgWbQiCqbbmOTpww5zea50AC8by/cTG1usrRvYnVwhyf4kGVozFgg4nCCR5xAUI/fb5tQBW8cg/Z7MOh5uO9iAf5wmdUQ7aTYQV5h1eKSIH6t/rK9k1cfpUIIISfkTVXTh9x6pUXLSTFdpAPF@DoLLnxxzUDzCqlU2bQWMCW@soxcNYUZxqhWk0m@j5zDXIKreifbkG2yG@3mhHldyU7k4TvqfVbCFpyl3LSGn46cbGMVSxripnMFilmvksNnHTR9uidT8NqrDb8ToeQFlrMxOTAI9v36voXovrDI9R5EiEv6dlb6dlEek7SBak4V44m@DjTSztTKv01znejUnE271ZdZcWLlxz1dDNHS5I4b@m@vGFu2KsHcea1qCuFK6OE1URC1kr5PKX3JeVRokzE4FH6kaRr/l7UPR9hmcj7Olk/fh3dQT4rz2pdkwkuzXWDzitHh4LWKWCzFFFTKSnOEQuVGVRlbYOpxQmt4HDOz8N2rRxDWSgaicNjJrW2@jqV04uMV5lJNMSK8dbAmjJGLCpxnQtMuBEbLFI9nPzIAsEwwWjKjNw1U3isC48tsMj1yFQrVpC3Bjg1bXKIl2EX@Q1/zGBPImfypacnzgjmI2m8WDcnCcRC91FqOpmS0gTmIvJRN@qeWSSuezwJcbqQ2LFOgaM6fbHBbuMY/FEkJ2xBYSTFLbpHKZrScYaiYd@7uhCJN87/5uedNw1aY/c7/khVsM1osBWWkzBwH/rhMIRzKPZxE172@x3cOvKC75pNqLVfkcUlXLfEEK2ZPefUoNkj@T08aYN0KpRTu4B8DQWROCG8PDuDMRksYHvXEK04cQmGOafSHcuBBo2Zp4tiZu4rON9gAdwJzmwkpOdk9IDSYb/R9HMOrdFCWv040tR2oCN98nk67EbgfoymtJeO89fLoPn7xhvc5z4vFp4WLZJd6evgQu7ps9jAiohkEhbhOnCp@MxxrLvhptwNZwHQU9uY6D8Qb/pXfrfrOxWaMThjSIvW0B9c@a2c4@z50SUw4IKVcTMJO@ze5aAphzu06GoQM8JKOPTkOow4DL@Yn@W6uMl3ZZ6DS6v4tpm6@ipogYDG4qTdw@0wX1jATYDQA4Uu/CERZd5VSZT47lnjwmuXCxxEETXg58S6m4jI0O0Ngyb1DJ9kOR0CJdcgcWXd1gQmVF@z04BxcG4aAjCPiSlgEDBXSffh4OhL8x/CQemGmTv2humZPEm/Ho8VGu7@ICDpGxOYe4WLWbhTBx@8re2r/d2tg4@Vvaqi5/d7ux9qm9VNtf6J77hxUc5eeNXb3W2SLtFtutya79KHVGWfSqY4wansfFLVX97vVff31e6eqr17v10jaAR@r7JzUKvue6q2s7F9uMm37wRB7eweqO3au9oBZTvY9bhWU8yJy6ndLfWuurfxll4r67Xt2sEnrnGrdrCDynCrX1HvK3sHtY3D7cqeen@49353v6rQMGeztr@xXam9q27mqH6qU1U/VHcO1P7byvb2REN3P@5U9xQrCVitXK8SlpV12sKiJm7nZm2vunGABsVPG0Q8QnDbU/vvqxs1PFR/qVJzKnufPA10v/rXQ8pEiWqz8q7yhhrnZL5DFeqXjcO9KtwlgRL7h@v7B7WDw4OqerO7u8m03q/ufahtVPdLytne3WeCHe5XPYWwhlw1wSBqUTo9rx/u15hutZ0DmjMO30PfwaVO/kiEISwrVHSTCQw1CLSWiLS79wlQQQfuAE99fFul73ugKVOrAipAo2LjwM5GFRIRD@xmqp3qm@3am@rORhXJuwDzsbZfdanDavvIUINCxidiHar0kFuNfiK85JGY1TGc63F3qtqWqmx@qAFznZs4YL@muYXJtvFW0zwHJ73WIUrQw5lB48I@WGnf/nTlwzvl7ROZ6Wc0kcekjd3NKs3I2rdVKk44pFlnZcKVkp1GM02USK8JlzUt//TyrB502z3YmEbF5ODjIjzzELnHRdiTY@eeAFb6fIULpNP1@odKnTa6@/W66z2kZAKN75XQx@D35XJ1GxENATtvHPy8fCl0X00Qau2JvuhkRT1cQCCnUP@JqL41LnxX5fMtXxeD8T4Am6OjUK5NznGVQqKRjR0RryWukk8m@D3Q7MAFMwZ8rlnHOSk0IzlTL6Q/3W/xi0wO1geSznLclc9jE8toBF98U41Uwi4R@I/2SBC0ucpc6Pu/n2UKdnXY8@fOer1WxnVNGc47pH3gWcb9TvFT/2yieHayPCPL1846kEBo9t28hInunzXJlO6X3IBblsGf@pB/XION@HzAqSlXxYfV@tAy80SKQyPJU9q1BcwruJOx5ntX@aX2Ebu5wuKz0sT3t9F3GVvQF4QXW5rwjrjcCf@8PZEMNMDYFweRJNAeMvJ5q4zRN4kyX1PGc2S6DlrQ/KG5@tzneZ1IQgvZy0bHrhOz8SAY2diTHH6zV3m3fri1RaIT2D5bWXq@XHIit1u/ePL7CfWwq1n2OtaneZzWaZxkjZINWvjwSLFcfMfszwyczyMjvLebTuOP8PMQ6W0kNZkgyNDcEMGLulDRS/mgQ0qxA45HjuHXqSNTM0Am0VQXrblojHiJ36C1EvOAVmbpjLnXRvgD2NHwN0M8apBmIM1i7HyXOJd2Fyz3UltGVZQ3N@y4B1lyKcPH4sYtogEfdbH@LKxr@U3zttWLoagyYrxyt3NJQuLRJBbK6FV0ZWS/Zz8j@gCYvYfRl180v9HjJ@3gjt3dNcJhZbhPZNyKSuKcOj6M1o0@0pBPEEkDTtVMTasKp/yuRorHnj5OjhyDWKOBUUGYFuj4JgGXIj8ik1WyBuzrOVd9FU6F8w7AKWmO1e/EudOao6GUjP8Q/W68UiiBFTk5EapdR3U4JsunyI@FIWeCTD9FD4b/D6TJFPirtOMk6DG1LCeAD6IkQxVa0faViRJcm4sG63Yjpqb96VMM5sbumPOoYfr2ZiT2NUQC3Ttj8@ETuz1sZ6YQAEyOgw17/EYqaecN2jq9Trm6OO5Jus2LfkbpucJMFbfgZpdPPF52eeZuBS@ucuWsyapwm4qq17JxO@VRT1umia28ehymBJxr/H/k5/kAJBrwzKXnorU6yVkFPcqMHNCulqwJpxV5TKJl6c2dt3bzynKRmZD9@ubLEIpArwGf2@3ksCI9Jeq5SY@LPBOrA/aCB4fi2CZj8tEu605ZEbPjA87jFh@GIPLI8BoTREegs6u@GJrKPGZFEVQSax3GfgYhbt0ckZan1esIez6ZBIdG2B92xZO9L6daJkdOHHxoDG1z@Zx61xgTyp2HNVtYLD@/3/Ogu4jK5FhCl0eUlWavN6ClYwPtJhy9YOzm1Ed96OB3w8uB9l9I81kw0CcSZtFP1WDZJLt3nmbEiTyjFgZDWCu0cswf3KQLHxqi4p5klF1WGWJew6Nr5tAxGC0UVWY1TlklmrBbUibiqlpW375JLiGodhnqMwWDMNpcsM4m14N7h2j4XfcGv2PuxxKo2/JbkWdSCySfBUon1brs47E5lKb3eyGfaFBX4AQkokRRDtIiRVWao59rdtJ6TanYOyZ8l3JLfryeiEmNthRVFDOurp2YbzlLnQkqLWrXoJGz0OLiEqMybcN1c@dmjL2FJq@tVeq4G4mUl7KIKD82S0c8idyMnj7hSR/ylx@HGD30BXfcegkKhLFmxb3qbTnH@EGn4GPgD1r2mSitZFqNPo7feOvT6zIvmqND7fav2RiG/ph2AM18MMozjHrmL73zbn2j12mcBb2gQfs0@IEficTD45gf0WFng951yAGEOKFlZWqN42fxLyNu2PAe3UuWLNdc4dDvZ2w1heFgXDkXNxF8cg4lwDiiKPN3f9JHWlTm2VJcyEnan7I@XtEt3Vn2aXFaYbnRBwAt4NYmNCjEhnTIhkmW8WnpVobT@zJYOJ6qrGq4d2jsJTB@QSTia5gExgaZW2oJdiOwM7sT46PWyGuxD8IBHC35mz5i4YQZ/uw1EKSZpMgraAq8VMWVglVUblFG8EOIh/Hd5F58/g/GnhD4CfSLT6dxyzRGYBHXNt6WQtmvaC@jhAurBwYso1kSkxQLzoKuZX7IUShGk1CTyeO7qMGaP7Qo0m72bnElRmSGNj6Ic5epk8ipj11MKnNqzmW/HViCVIaZwt0M639Pf5YHPy5x5eQMgmlDQ85YSN9FqiZRCWFwJ9RrbZTFp/L3R8zi4kN7bYKA5WkqZ1Y45kzKrFzYAiWQ@RXXWr0BCePUBPW0qsdcOOz15x5IvTtlx1TPbNNo3XTd7yoCC7OVabKcbzFpy2M8jkvOJD4TTJOkGGuaEQ9h@8rPEZtPEnFUrmO8levj79DhLprFelPRpBL1d0vGPibFK2j0mokmGlKMO5yUlqLvR3VqeP1uCaJhyvaqzhKjDpFRH8ujBWqCTBGVHk4h5j6N@wQ9WkQ51Nsi2tn9cydRJ5XkjMtTk5Rwcgl6wnE7jDZJLvXbUL6AmzhZ4UZCKlpwjrwxX@UVs6dwMowEAYhVsZ@Nz6HkBDfurAk@4ugA7Uwd2kJFSCJ6WrM1HCKn/xHB2Cu/PtzRGg/1cbZ4UhJIowgS7So4132QjL05vR7VRwzlFiloiE8hRdSiW7Lp/OGt@tm2UD6CIKU5WWv6Fjw0xlULhA39sZPqI6yB46p0ycSISg6EOosGGgu0Sznr@LJdxeovGAjHQ7tBDyPaQMjnDH4WdAm4814uRNRGkVFrjCyuJreMNldl16RIzFDyDvLroShLXd64EgBfMKby5SJBgFtTxh6XAux6x@a8BKK6j6hguYhhSR/ZK2qs5zklHUTVGZ4tWTkK03K8sGFkpwKhhcX0PDEitGaZniWGQhPdVFysHM@ntyfOQQtiw/tCceoK3StJGkY9JwTksM8FN5YoR0XlFTQHc@KzJTeRGPE3p74oWKmFyVSiT4ThUbY4mbpSSKQmql1cTBZNlCR6uHatiUQihWsjHEmFn/vHpim2y/NIJ9TaZCRWGVo/G2G5aZdJ@7bcb6FaZaNss8Yw8GzLcLP9qkuIlYRT9vsdsKs5vjKA7/afbq3RTDWY6FgB7JfOGLtkZEPIK9YUpno0Cztd42kvclBg9rS9tvpwsLWVcPt6OjaKRhf@YKlQKICJT23n90a3GkdJQS@fzJ1vX3Y6@f71XwYfTvMs@32fQwK8NDton7qEBkWY6w3OJDIEcKCsyJ3VhqzY61@223YIBtxQovOo2ySn9oageAIKIqWXDwd8AMQg9QT7KxqI9v2qotF33ZCFpoZirqGoNFSCr1Lm9ozIgw9t6GdHN1UMDILZaDPRvOWW175iBkFkE@4sdl/sfo3Vk1Nv/U6n56mPCEEMTwEzN5MFtrbsAgXJghtGtu69DNkfraf8q6Bj2RUji83rAGcmJhNnwviFh2/8Pf@sOupnUkefUzStUJMX0MwF@Kf2VOos5Wpn8Q8AK3xIaD8o90Wjn2kynSYz01SvR3D8RBg9LXpT9z6JLC6fiWmafT83iDod3Rw7a6Cmu7wWML7suXu5JXdkj4ibOh4V26BhQWBonOBz5WElYGr2jxOLV8N2@2FSkcMASMf@kESUSCg/JxD5DoBHoB5@RE940f6nLA3rrQmHIrLAQbCO23IHBeoo4DiPm@U/rjOVSkXN9hcWVKWyTg/ZrKqsV9QmPqyvq016X8f7k/Li0lJJZO6m@5U@rpuPN2qdYPAJ50LzfLBJr5RWht0YtLXRxbP58qxXmq2XV9dKYf6osg6zfnr673/@1//@l3/LV/TLf@BlnV@OPkeZcrlcfrb5dfbJTQnvR5snc7OnR7P9k7mzErjsf9lreK82zDZi9dHc4NRJyyxgfWU9UrPPZu8zuqgyQQEvGoPfSbq8VOlmmE/rr6FEjmIZm2761ncfdpSntIU3QQcmt/KERJqAjnEcT73T9KGAR/MNUZJwgR6olJe7FXNwD3cwUYboViWtPfHwmvXKh01L7EkBtrg0Y2WDbuh3cQJ@xWteaZ7jNOg3GNY1/@Y/vwvP1nsjNX@cUfMFNe@p@VSKf4rLL@irO5sPYJ0r2Wg7kEp5lBJfLUDNUIUBL/R4/8CxdibI7TizHLIHkIybCs4sVnBetPtjYxkJuBaeOTOIxankiIQvmVAk/XW2e0Pd8pVy3KQSpja8UKjrXQxXZt2oRP2LJVAjFEWAuOYLIcjLHlWJmz62SMZT3nzRfe1wNCEGDLLuvdnicY8PNBfNdrXOc2IvhTBHrD4vXzE3lsQYmtFGitQfI8AXKrKdLLAl4Vx6zhEtb6uV3Eyxwrbbp5lPdB3G/tDopkuhP5XFBKLNbRNutqvtWrQit1yvqFQQXa9YVaUmdb@VYxW5uOwMg742V@DaMaC@RrXdyEhCjzIggSM@@1/eHmF8UGA8RU10iwTLGqtWD02XkdDVpunUwW5Obo4sIuQ/Z2hsf5sY226erUQMOwgPMFKRKl@7EXRC7XVlwMQ@awxOER2w0eaAakO5N@PzPIRfncC4146QzjFkVjmPxzM1Jd0fNM4uGp5K7/QOBo1xjaYtWvkMmzmXWggXTEACg09XPa15BmFpke4SpkjUFNYcQvCCzliHR5O@TUU2J@hSMxS02xUMggQ7MSX9b4m@mqBjzNU/0Ak2yreEd3QbqUUsS15oGmlIKdtshofZraHjmBrssRMNnJQjqEYj0/CCLnSJifaCL35JknfgI0DXndJWgNoUYfkF6sfsdOZ3G4nJqd9xjKF/vqRkXsR45lCUoo3kmECpxTjiHbCideTnpBcImZuMOyNnJpOZOQ51OLe0PY@wk@9IFz/fUEEUgI4DmLFliDrsBiIsJ2aoOAZGTtVY858gtDuNM8JvfN0YgxWP05lXj/Lu0efj7sl85rj77fiLy5hokWxm2axK68tsI7H0WKGZMe8lXo1WWmhcDR53kxmOu0psWCwSECL5zNHn/Mm3PCF0nEZQ@uO0ECTRZcAkf399eYDP30IzncQin3Zm3HnXdH7mVdFVNLfyL/pQPrjyS1iYTSUf09M@Z9AmUGyn@8elmJyE@ZXFwrPF4jPaCZ35o@zAv8R8mw0vT/0RLSVCbGdp6jn@kuCGBCFuRmGjRB9H1E4JayK2J6E2UtIiVA9zrseJ2IrK5IQnKD9Rmd2lwsTFjfI0cPmIDb@niOVMXvYFJaqDFvdlMH@GvQvU0wgh1yatQ4QjoWUgOiJ8hJoFZBN85S4Odc1wmWM7p5zagO9WBkLdm09bs0W3183qxZqbmythEQ2rmc5KYaUwOUZvDdHECJ3Vi6m5R6q49ur5f/377h/pYXptMf9xQL/D9B/p5ZW0PNIDvT01b1fptfQqsi3fpMd52gPT4/P/@k8qv/YXgoOU8Sr9WVsysJbH6bVsmYt8S68t00NxcZHq/Z@//Y3aMCs7NsRina17ihErGYpsNLrMu5SuamilbEvnYrHChlmAIRqGtDenFyhGjRZXCnxMl9ZaFVe@9nxl9FH0FM@KWUNWFZKTDKNPQSsjKVBGBVkBaVQo2srS3TBqG2DeGE316@Pcckg7gF@1OkdUZaS68TiEytCsbIuoAzNSI@3n5WGt8CoVqXe8TBmdkpJZQmJrp2XtytPS/wE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/sjrq3)

Janet has `#` line comments, double-quoted strings and strings delimited by any number of backticks.

Line 66: ````` [``]```` ````` closes ``` `` ```-delimited string and a tuple opened on line 23 and opens ````` ```` `````-delimited string.

Line 610:  ````` ````(print 346)9 ````` (9 is for YABALL).

Comment: I *cannot* believe this challenge is still going, 346 languages in a single polyglot is an incredible achievement on its own, and especially considering some of the insane langs in here

Comment: This is insane. Congrats for actually managing to do this!

Answer (score 10):

## 25. [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 220 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::  (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#3]#echo 21#===2|/=1/24=x=9+/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6//1''19+6
```

`␛` represents a literal ESC character, as per previous submissions.

This program prints [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), **19** in Reng (test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**8** in  Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OjogICgyMilTIztuNCIxNCIKIz4zTjZAMTVvfD4gXip0dHQqfisrfn5+JQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKI3wKcHJpbnQoKGV2YWwoIjFceDJmMiIpYW5kIDkgb3IgMTMpLSgwYW5kKzQpXjE8PDY1Pj42MikjQDQ2KDgrOSs5KzkrOSs9ISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSMzXSNlY2hvIDIxIz09PTJ8Lz0xLzI0PXg9OSsvCiM4G2RnZ2kyG2AgfDF8Ni8vMScnMTkrNg==&input=), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), [**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LczBTgIxEIDhe1@BS@3E0NJomdlS2LKz2bMHD3hUCSgIJGZXyYZwaPrqq4nmP32Xf4DLBoNTlQru7f67UTpGE2OUUhOZJ1i2XqFXAuriMTQ461It15O@7yfZ2pzzrQDO7UO1UkhqKeBZQBJf51Pba72/bD@1wpcrfZAy23YnS9mdJRbmTk9/ab1ZY1WFWV0HMtD4oBe2/I9vDMPfCOcGilfYvx87SQjMTMkxOvJ85dI6AYvR7nA40WgjE6bgHI7HWNowDD8).

The `1|6` is used by both Retina and Japt and the `//` serves to comment out the end of the code so that Japt doesn't output anything else. I feel like 26 should be fairly 'easy' to sneak into the end since SMBF needs a trailing `6`, so anything that will output the last item in the code (being `26`) should be at an advantage... Perhaps [05ab1e](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)? Good luck!

Comment: I had a look at 05AB1E. It *almost* works very easily; the main issues are Hexagony (this one's easily solvable), Pip, and Japt. (The problem is that Pip comments start with two spaces, and Japt doesn't like that at all, because a space is the equivalent of a closing parenthesis; this causes Japt to add opening parentheses to the start of the program to balance, leading to a syntax error because the closing parentheses are commented out.) 05AB1E next still seems like a good idea – it'll output `26` for almost any program ending `26` – but maybe you'll have to move the Pip earlier.

Comment: Followup: `$//` works as a comment marker in Japt that's happy to see spaces later on the line. I might have another try in a bit, but if someone else wants to get there first, go for it; testing a program in 26 different languages is exhausting. (Also, it's too late to edit my previous comment, but I should have said "almost any program ending `"26`".)

Comment: @ais523 Agree about tiring testing, such hard work! What's annoying is finding a problem in Japt and having to re-test the others! I did really enjoy this challenge though. I wonder if there's a record for the smallest polyglot with most languages...

Comment: The problem is precisely that `//` is a comment marker in Japt, but Japt doesn't *know* it's a comment marker, so it tries to balance parentheses in it and ends up making things worse. `$//` avoids that problem by telling it not to parse the stuff until the next dollar.

Answer (score 10):

## 26. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 224 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):::  (22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++~~~%
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[
#|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#@46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)=#print(17)#3]#echo 21#===2|/=1/24=x=9+/
#8␛dggi2␛` |1|6//1"'"'--1+26
```

`␛` represents a literal ESC character, which you likely know by now if you're here, but I'm reminding you *just in case*.

This program prints [**26** in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**25** in Pip](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**24** in Thutu](https://tio.run/nexus/thutu#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**23** in Hexagony](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), **19** in Reng (test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**8** in  Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OjogICgyMilTIztuNCIxNCIKIz4zTjZAMTVvfD4gXip0dHQqfisrfn5+JQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKI3wKcHJpbnQoKGV2YWwoIjFceDJmMiIpYW5kIDkgb3IgMTMpLSgwYW5kKzQpXjE8PDY1Pj42MikjQDQ2KDgrOSs5KzkrOSs9ISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSMzXSNlY2hvIDIxIz09PTJ8Lz0xLzI0PXg9OSsvCiM4G2RnZ2kyG2AgfDF8Ni8vMScnMTkrNg==&input=), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), [**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LcyxTsMwEIDh3a/QxdwJ1a4VzF1c07hxlLkDA4xA1UJLqYQSqKKqg@VXD0igf/qWf8TzhryFGrx9vfluQYWgQwhSKmb9iMvOATkQ2JT3vqV5nxq5ng3DMMvG5JyvBcbcreoHIIalwCeBSXydjt2g1P68/VRAzxd@Z9Dbbicr2Z8klbpQt780Tq@prv28aTxrbJ1XC1P9F690xL8R3WksX3D/9tFLJowxcrKRLLt4iZWxAheT3eFw5MlGJkreWoIpTIuCDPtx/AE).

I wish I could explain this a bit, but I mostly just stumbled through this blindly. Never heard of/used 05AB1E or Pip, and never used Pyth (which gave me the most trouble).

05AB1E saw most of the program as an unclosed string (from `")and 9` onwards), so that needed to be closed. Pip and Pyth didn't cooperate with the extra double quote initially, which turned into trial and error of single/double quote placement until they complied.

The exact math used for Pip was mostly arbitrary, as long as it resulted in 25, so toying with that got me a plain 26 at the end for 05AB1E while still calculating the 25 needed for Pip.

Comment: You should probably note that you need to pipe in empty input for this to work (e.g. `< /dev/null`), otherwise the interpreter hangs waiting for input

Answer (score 10):

## 46. [Cubix](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cubix), 946 bytes

```
#  5"16" 3//v\(@;# # \D'[af2.q]'# "14"<;n4
#/*`3 gkggZ">[77*,;68* ,@;'1,q)  ␉␉␉␉(22)PSPP( 
#yx␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{#z}# (prin 45 ) (bye)<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++ndL+++<-][PLEASE,2<-#2PLEASE,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2DOGIVE]>+.---.>][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.>]|
#[yxyx0l0v01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1(d111x0eeU0bx0b0o1d0b0ee0ee00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100(^_))46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
#|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"__*
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#seemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp/*/
#define␉z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(   )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<>//
=end #//
"""#"#//
#>27.say# /7Jn~49c53c'43'p;|
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#zsss!]#echo 21#^_^_*///$/*23!@4O6O@Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpJd9tIkj4X/kJd0iBtAiQBcLHkhQQt2Zb7uTZrLNn9nklaAsEkCQtbYZFIydKb68ybQ9/7Msf@H32dX9F/pOaLTHDR5qo6zHtDS2AiMzIiMiIyNvm3En3YfuQvpn6UsYynGRsn3ilPTPZywXYcL91qtRVFQCXROHe9cMqyGWdeGOcZm3g@TxXXyViPxQUWkwasxBLujCWYMokSRltYcOIzj7lxzEa@MzNdgKVRQEsZT@KE45mykPMxS2PuehPPFSQYn2c8TL0oTE3muSfszPN9NuY@NqzpunUgY3m6MSWpmMo4Uhg@bnyDy9VbmQMm5MuT8thJxEkjFotjLw98ljhxDCaVEjsA45kX8JR5WSVl3Ek9Eh@2pDwcCyHFK8FGzAk3T8lOPYc54DdPBO6UJxmOZwq8bMYTDpQOEZ8mTsC0s8TLIAKS4S7b507CDhPOdVCB7HnqOjH4uEYSxCKikNFBTKGjbrey9@5NBbqSO0wnzpRS0j78tx8Uh5k2Kx918GurakfZ@@U1uygPaAwugAz6jBPN0Zl9xVJrMOD4nTdH1jS5VIBVgVR8ZkVxZgGzk2Rgbz0yTltm7G@QZd0bmtiwHwk1hi7Y25B9rItzuXmScHCxFqlzgiP7UTiFNHHUJA9JGiHbbkABbhSO0zrjp5BZFEoNRWdCvoczDypLSSHOCOJxXJK8tH0hTlg/LK@Q55JuGvm5gMPONCPzg0ywlTC@nbCPbOJ4Pm3BOqGSXCc8zf2M9uThmPQeeCEfm2zJhhuNCSiITkHOAVIxgesSbFwywRSAoYZIHJWW/vW3v4@nU@DZdd0oGRfG@pGNIzcPwLAjmHVgiGSuUej4gi3A1Ym63A4Cp47vjZ2MyIeLgoRgQlA9i3J/zCIQTM48XKyZc4rLOJlwN@PSxKM8A491Fjgn0jV40m5x8MAZQbGCgKAtjm2wnVfQksulwRhBnk2eMiPeY5XU@qy9eK69eDDg4E039WrZsqYdWJtZFVN4q3zLcD7urvVJ1nPoRXSL/HiWw2dgJUxjeJOEhOk6OE5KTiWDu6uzkRC08EQwdHFFz3gl4WyEe708mLARaQO036B7W2BY63QJd93E@HjDwmCdMLIsveUk/OgMhAVv5DNh0yERd6YOSGXFgXblgSRFMXP9aCchLJ2wjTh7aow8aIfsAK6mUMbGGQHebkkYYJPa27gUgbMAFle66LUmmTeBkgPYbbJgLqfLgFvBpZ8jIrkwjNSDHUUT1jBaW1u/o/wssXaNT5ZjnFvf1DEd/oaad9mEnzHfCae5M4UhRyG2OK7L46y4QThJmuGO3HSDYtIofLqZzpTyzk3awrcV3n6DBnkfqb3CQztk9hBUAFEbPm45c5KpuIls7CW4L/7iJnUAnN4grh4TyDUGjtV7WFgGJhgZn3M3z3DdYMhnM8@dwXaJu1BeWOkdb5LH1CZ1uBxjsiJNzDR7j1qKaa2miI17URik0dt44PUJVe/ahFD@5oQ8ICLvAUV9uKplmBW3YJUKrM4OYfxAQSThv@YQLmzPm4YE4oSrEL3hxbw0rMCte6kHCVGwJbs8fPuOfPdfucw3ICMZdzYdb4TsA9uLYEoLS4Ep3J1FzAhZpeBBU0Xs@wK2rDRxxcDYCPiqbkJaGklNLC0RfZHp083gx3q34QTJSp31VXVYR7zxU6g7zH0fL3koroPG9QvYhcvT1IRx4w6alDmAO7XG9cvrgNksic4Yv9Q7lbvI/UmFuPnIm///U4hgSz5xqA0tiKk/ooZbgP/HerhFD5p4GyLIwP2ei2gQknfLg9x3MpkQuFEOOa@0gcjg2A2pwEPI6CckSewnj2LXBCnVOtUWifmcksqBosaLbBaF7eveR12vtGR299EKEIzMeHF33FU3UYkNP3vhSUS8WcFydNQwm1vXUKAwuL1z4qUz8bgGeout2ytidxqMJuJxB0BIpnjD4MVCEIWRJA4JeaFjvRdfJjzsXRxcd2TXyL/k0PGUG8/a1sgLrRGf3Af55uXLtwJmMhp59wFBDFT/LL/vAEvy0V1SQv4yuxXo2DU5H@ZJ5htjK6Nv/j//Poa8b2tj5ixSZLwnq8FRyM9IM8bkXuUUW@lFPO5W5JfcRzX0Ozhch7Jcx18N7sb1nL3nsHbkI6EogsCp7@MiQ2RwMLfNGTfBz8d8@X03UiHD6/FS7g69wIAtb5sNoUC8Ug5Amdh9WG4EfYmGioPEj5yxJcs1j681KmXP5840ChfWRkQxk9EfYHUZl9m6PstmeZbLJxVlv6c7L6bfb13BArKxtfuyuVd83QMPJrbvs115bRJ4F@ON75xYIxoeTTC8@6jyMIk3RQW4/L4P7K8HseNy6yylrzvN5mdkUz7q6oNfPhzsf9N@BEKkWYkvn3eiexu6CGph9vuYcEpfPP6M4Qk7cB0f1teWtkdtEWNDTN4NwfrOaEF1/OzP2xBRndZqzIjWxcq66xLH929y3bs3yb6M2OdGKCf570UdhA4vwHFb443hvTbhRca6JEqlIU2oBrzD9zinDjNc30lhGlkhXX4KbYjHt0yVIoRLNrMefctQbzC1LEvvq2zWO2PPjRC9Y6FmevHxcl9Qu5k90IrMBN6LBsmqYknrRV8Hc15S1PHpqlVWWq@y0AlEHUfjZZLRkcViOhMdAhR1Y/i8D6Enkjw3SmTJI@tqEV/@@Y9x0TiZclS@gZcin5mG1OpDXTOLzl5IugX13diBsAQKXDJfZoHGq12WnnmZO5PtEqRNH94cPi1q3aLhiJd98nUbTMhjY2kCFpyMi7JMMjOOuLygBd3VruWZIO48CNmZN85myKwOPJSvopZe1nfgJCEwFNURXfA6e8vGnG6/SGK/5Mi7/Cg6EakzcfLPf8gKH4tABq4xXpIXLacNigzG1hRltSuTvCWSc55EBYhGMobR5JDIAu6Fy3mduTNHtB4SkxnLwpvIyOL71e4BM1B5U8OU6vCON9HKu@//8rHfGNpXLLCQCViUxgq5qQ@NJ81UrbMlSOeSI/HdXG5geb1aYWp5rhbHouac6EWtbEraG9NoLNS1LKQD0dcTZsfPRCEtuiUh3QlqmKFYSDO86gK1bLDZZQ0pRIC6wDjI2BZ1lTlEgpHsBDLq04Ki2MLKc/aVzchYDJc1txp4kxLxqRER2OvMbTNZtl7zUS5CzGnLbLVtcZ7ykd3tiVHCxxG1qvqfB@OhlS7FMhjMHzZac5LbI4tuzd4vry/KZq/x9WvqLJiqXlY6op5Qn6usfLH/dn/v4HD38MMBZHipF9LbL/qvopfoFL1lGHKeLm9lITxqQ4tWgGgl02aBuyy3SmwITIknLsDyKoPCRj1hSlPUNKdW0/WNrvjeHK4JFkvdSdFdVJacRUXvbKlC3NCZLBJROa6MMF0VfHSECV0hH0qgikZE5ZS0wEjjJtv1U5j8eAwdjhYZlwWOrPFWhZ5aYmXHXJ2izlSFYFP7dg8FGj5DJHKP5eaygBOY07vakANu/etvf5etx0GG8X8U4wnG/yXHny2S0u1eleRxJRoSy8e3@yyFX5EHD5z5xplk9QbjDnMUuQEkeCoEQuA3jrtGo/U/QpzQAWRJFkpGKcjxZKjNsix@blnkh6eRPzFFqs7nUANs2kR2av2aUyMYF8na3tp@3EQmyI3TJULRs5hS3igR6vpzpjLl1Ivt45HLut0uU1Eb@9ze7kg5WmXnc1s9XjFaBqwifXafYQ@2rHdgrVds08pOranTVmbbrNKssGEH7liqBTdaEwOA6DQdSnGAF438ppAUld18njEYc7JYhiIEApRwAclJ/DlgicgAIolbV5Vbpgt@sSKSQ@9amCyM7g4rYTCG/77DSEKM/1OO@4OGcTW8q219h5msMsbD6ISH6TfadUZGEN75ZuPOK3ZvNO6WU3DEWvcadV32FNf2pZabKmis8brKrUJik@gys1uR2Nx5@2hLxwDRFpUMtEV/CQLUK3hOL3vOdn7kYcgXTIPhBQ706eTI/xK9vvwrZH3VPL6tkb3KhR/BxspWR7jkziWEfzxgg2wwGYSkgc7C@t4yrc6FVvbthYULove08sxu1trVWq0cVrVySCby6BF58ssyLPDIVE11DiCj7OsduD1YrF0OO2Wnq5XHdqsqduAVjvICG65Sy7woO5dW@RGMoI6ZhNO94lo51SluN0yzeQn@vkReWLbqgRNfaCpT59RyJ/Jlr1YjHszyETFwZQ0OauAcNnVgifjRKfyONQ064n5WrlvVb7@VGNtSm9sqa1vW6UDb6ZTg3QevK31n0jJ/HVZKTG0@Vrud8LFSsqrHbTY9mU4/qb3@kyfVemf7aZXVdzqVZv1XnbHv8NFaLX3/YH9fY0ppMf@u095@sKOUjrvH7DulZCul7rDW7Zs9Y9jrK6WL0vllSSgwZI@3mI7MZMH1LkWP@fsaffqvezX5Ccc/4dk1hv39n/Z2D/bqra5Rai3HBx9elpqY2Gq92X0lX2m9Ta/v93Zfv/twWG@9fveXtx/3hr2aaRiG2RuCg/fzh72rq6saq11VsyyrmnOl9Lo3/2AZXVD7SQeEgCbwr0qpv5gv5g2/cdponjRPMPDmjS/zxqwxa2rjZrM5b3D@oTGaN0aNqDnGk3P6aQR48RqTeWPaCBshwUUYuPOGi8EEzyktTYDoC/55jQbhb5zOQchvik@joX0@0vXH29rT2rPin/0A/H1VhGI1jZ86vqY2B/PWpKXqiBzaMx0m2GzruqE1KJI81j83u11te0vv9bTtlo7lija4wM@lTo@@pg/1Swzkj14pEeWvtmU3rdZje24/63fLtZ2asYOP3at1i68XJSFSc2gpR0evdw93j47sZsmylJI5MNVmSz06qpJOO5SMRT43/WjK2s8UFR8Cs0d8CgugDSlHrs33HZ5zfpbnZ3z1eYX8/8sXeJY4tqqAHPMJIv935yyFF4kmFbdiNF@o7afIi9pPVKUET0P9mS51siJz1lOoC6nhLuhiu6Yfl44Hlap1QVWMdq53Lq1q5fhYKVcIsELMGO3ocVQql8tKt6e21Xdmt0fc0h/riW3iXvBf6rWemMjOSsx68kN49fiZu9V2K4/blbgDm3n6/Xg69VrfH3/3tfl1u2xZlUprizG7JPXWfKKXztM0fTAsCc/aapY@H30@qsLjlK1qq/1g5/G77Xc7n1qt1rNnz9TW9m@W9a0ggNWVh0SdnKR5cJeL3E28nx3KncKVm8Tg5xweeSU7RsLzvRFJ79qcFOjmlPg/A5hTiC8haRqg4nHrIqFjVepj9Yc6uxDZojdhGq0izDVl1iqT8yxPQtboKBKIuiGd1RBUSNfMJgCaJBepeXazw7wuIcM3PGtBgT7LHTWbhj4PNcGFN9Q7K5gVJz3s3uBlY3@tJsEvJVvyPG4wlseWa6tXsBdQpelqxW79BgASdcBUBo1Kccw/cgyEdm2Foc7@9DFu7EcQ0ZdnEiysF4v5tSoulWpWDzoKHbsad5QfNVe/oODWuQoePXI/x/1g2NEDO6PvWi3oXConmidBqpkd2EazE4PZTtav1byhHeg/arFgPrAbAAZtwpzqFytNh3ahrlSvn/dD4yoc1t/0w1pzWM/r1U/2ed2xG/U5fiG2ul//FcJbilLL7PNa2HG6@KU4e00SsZ3WnM61Kdpyovn2ed8Z2g2942NjrfYGhwGfad@v1YY6iPtYvL2x4z965NT83rzjG4ZOUJ/bL970MwyGNZven2tOd/7ivJ9j/3MN3zbI@DqYx77rOgA@8NeBjKX61qxLHufE3hzsBbZd/fSi@qlqP3hw3p8bwbAuxf@8sVY8MT8n5jdtRKt@2jQsIRJReGrqQ@/5Q7OaMrUO64OQ6/HGTslh9RNW4vVtuPxf)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .009718 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1008 bytes; 953 or less beats the top VIP score)

### Rundown

This program prints **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.

### Minor golfing:

I cleaned up a few characters here and there. I'd detail what, but that was several days ago and in the interim I've had to pull two all-nighters, so I barely remember. I do know that I managed to get rid of one of alphuck's `ps` loops in the first half, so the alphuck/evil line now begins with a single `s`. Overall, I golfed down to 939 bytes (and I've saved my TIO link for the golfed version of #45 if someone wants to see it).

### Cubix:

@Chance has mentioned this language a lot, and after discovering that Octave wasn't going to cooperate and not having any other ideas, I decided to go ahead and add this. I wanted to use pretty much anything else, as this is going to be a beast to maintain, but I was out of ideas. (I *did* notice that we have a 46 in the code already though. Not sure if there's a way to leverage that. If someone thinks of one, I'm more than happy to delete this answer and use Cubix later).

Cubix/Hexagony interplay is going to be a mess, so I'm *hoping* that the way I intertwined them doesn't make that any worse.

For following Cubix, you'll want [this interpreter](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/). The Cubix code itself is fairly simple, the pointer wanders around the code until it hits the `/` in the middle of the Hexagony capsule. Fortunately, Hexagony's output command `!` is a skip instruction in Cubix, so we avoid the terminating `@` and enter the reals Cubix code `4O6O@`, which just pushes the digits we need, outputs them, and exits.

### Hexagony:

We're back to the left-to-right capsule, which automatically saves us two characters, with an added `$/`. The `/` is the mirror Cubix needs (`>` would also work here for Cubix, but Perl and Hexagony wouldn't like it) and the `$` lets Hexagony jump over it. One of the filler `z`'s is now gone as well.

### Incident:

Cubix's output detokenized `O`. I remedied this by capitalizing one of alphuck's `c`'s in the evil line. Evil ignores capital letters, but `c` was performing a useless action for us. This created a token with two `C`'s from Incident (conveniently almost exactly where the now detokenized `O`'s are) to rebalance things.

### SNUSP scare:

In trying to have Cubix dodge a minefield of `o` and `>+<`, I rearranged various characters in the SNUSP line (though I didn't know that's what I was editing at the time). I checked the driver for each change and nothing ever complained (which was worrisome, but I just ran with it). As I was typing this up, I checked Modular SNUSP and it failed ("so *that's* what that line's for!"). Thankfully, other edits meant I could restore the line to what it was before without breaking anything. Close call.

### Tips for the future:

We still have a filler `z` on the last line. Also, the `#z` on line 7 (PicoLisp line) can be exchanged for a single letter Japt command (I used `Q` for a bit). You can't remove both though, or `z` will become a token. But, two of the `z`'s in C/C++ can be changed to any other character. All of these things combined could be useful for generating tokens and for letting you slip in just a few characters without Hexagony and Cubix blowing up.

Comment: May I recommend using [Glypho](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho) at some point.  It might be nice because it is mostly character agnostic.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks for the suggestion! We're definitely starting to run low on ideas. Glypho looks workable as long as the aaba instruction doesn't error on an empty stack since this also happens to be Trigger's character agnostic jump code in line 2. If it does error, working an instruction into line one will be a difficult. Maybe a ~5 language solve just for that instruction. Not necessarily impossible though.

Comment: Awesome :-) Any idea what's wrong with Japt?

Comment: @ETHproductions I have no idea. It came up in Chance's last answer, not sure if they have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Emoji might be a good candidate; it ignores everything that's not an emoji.

Comment: @RobertFraser But Python'll blow up because it'll only recognise ASCII characters, unless specified with another encoding, which will cause more problems down the line.

Comment: @ETHproductions I've gotten as far as figuring out that Japt bombs out on line 607 of the japt-interpreter file with the error "Cannot read property 'm' of undefined". Something about a Japt.flag.m. Sincerely both Cubix and Japt are node.js programs, and cubix works, as well as Japt as a stand run, I think it's likely a switch that needs to be set when running Japt in the driver.

Comment: @Chance I believe the problem happens because Japt isn't getting any input, which breaks the internal input/flag parser. Hopefully this bug will be fixed when Dennis updates Japt on TIO.

Comment: @ETHproductions So the stand alone Japt doesn't have anything in Tio's input field either. You think it's maybe seeing an empty string?

Comment: @Chance I think the way `japt-wrapper.js` is set up causes it to expect code and input, and because we're not giving it input, it's using `undefined` instead. It's been updated on TIO now, so I'll check if it's working

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working. Is it giving the same error? (I'm not sure how to debug it through TIO)

Comment: It works now \o/

Answer (score 10):

## 54. [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 1207 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPX (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k\4O6O@1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
### <$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
'p\';if [[ $argv[1] == *"1"* ]];then echo 50;else echo 54;fi;exit;';print((eval("2\x2f5")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///^_^_X222999"26
```

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkufGL9QlDdIGQBIbKcqSQdCibblHVeWSxpJd/UxSEggkSVjYCotESabfXGfeHPrelzn2f/R1vqJ/pCYiE1wkUa6qQ783lAkkkJkRkbFH0L9W8EOO4uB6EsQ5yWmWEy/1L2mqkVfXZM/xs3azJQhsVRp7hetHE5JPKfGjpMjJ2A9oJrhOTrokKaFoOCAVklLH48uEcZwS3ELCi4D4xE0SMgqcqeaSwGdrszjE@ZymSUrhmpGIUo9kCXX9se8yPITOchplfhxlGvHdC3LlBwHxaAAbVsjdBgAjRbb2iqPSBC8WCHzc5B6py6cqhTURXRyXJk7KjhuThJ19ceqr1EkSIFKokGMgPPdDmhE/lzJCncxHHsKWjEYe41Sy5G5MnGj9lOTSd4gD9BYpg53RNIfjaQwumdKUAkgHkU9SJyTyVernwAJkZI8cUSclJymlCmABAdDMdRKg4w5KQBYjhhwPojFBdTrS/uFbCQTGd2hOkguVtHXy798LDtFsUj2z4GuLoiXs//SG3FYHOAYqABgINUllRyH2V5LpgwGF78wc6ZN0LgBUAbgSED1Och0gO2kO5K1G6mVTS4I1tKRzTxJrSsRXeSALchCRjw12LrdIUwpUrFjqXMCRgziaADfhqGkRITcism2AANw48rIGoZfAszjiEoqvGH9Ppj6ILEOBOCNgj@Mi57kBMHaCCYDmlfxc4M3ioGDrYGeWo/oBT2ArQjwYk49k7PgBboF5BMWpTmlWBDnuKSIP5R76EfU0siDDjT1cFMaXgM4BoOwF2Ey4ZmmMKFgMYojZUXHqn3/9mzeZAJye68apVyrrR@LFbhECwQ4j1gFFRHWNIydgZMG6BmLn2wHBpRP4npMj@ui6RMGIYFiv4iLwSAwI0ysfDGvqXIIxjsfUzSlX8bjIgcYGCZ0L7h98rrdw8NAZgWAZAoabHVsle69BSi7lCqOGRT7eIWqyT6RMP5VfvpBfPhlQoE3RlFpV1ycWaJtWY6/gSfqW4nzsreSJ2nPix2hFQTItwGfATJQl4E1SZKbrwHEydCo5@LwGGTFGM08Eis5M9IpKKSUjsOvFwZiOcB3A/SrabQlhJdPFursqRr01DQPtBCXLswdOIoivADGjDR0n6HSEyJ2JA6jy8kA9fiCOkb25e7SLCDQdoY0o2VFHPkgH9QBcTSmMtTPC8laTrwFoXHprRhE61wDF5S56JUnij0HIIehtek1cisYAVkG5n0MkBVOMzAc9isfEUJvt9m8IP0/1nvpJd9Qb/ZsyxsPfE3OPjOkVCZxoUjgTUOQ4gi2O69IkLy0ITpLlYCP33SB7qZY@XcumQnXvPm7m20pvv4YDvQ@XXumhHVR7YFQIrFYDsHLipBNmicTzU7CX4Po@dlhweQ@5eI5L7hBwLj5CwiIwgZLRGXWLHMwNFPlq6rtT0F2kLuIGy73jffTwah07uBx1vESNxJjdZ01B05evkIxHQago0YdwwOsjqO6dF0z46y@@DdnJwg2A4yWJ4KHW3mq6o4HulUyDaH6MmQS4v0XoZpa1TC@W/AQGf4@BKaW/FCAw0Gd/EuESJ1qG/TXP6GeRBKHCz3zgOgZw1PWTg0OMBz9TnsMA33ksW3fmMWQ0sL0M0DixEIJA3WlM1IhIJQ2yyOLpZyBLz1KXDdS1JEJUNOCTjPxiUwtAn3ledj@gku7DdQyl1CB9URw2IIYFGahQVAQBPBQRMzGZKregay7NMg0MBnirYTYC1Il1qszvLsynaXxF6FyxpE3o/qBAXhcjf/b/UCIu0sWvcKo1MbBXv0cODxb@iwXxAB@I4iCCyAU@/YaFmAhdZhEWgZPzLMONC@DzUhwQbhzb4BI8AR79CJkX@dHHgDiGPG2Vv7OUf4aZ6kAQk@t8Gketuy5NXM00ecr4UQ8hwmnJ9eZgLq6DYhve@dFFjLTp4WJ0Zmhm@w4IKDke7hz72ZRd7ix9QNbDGbY7C0djdtmwIEJVvKfxbCKMo5gjBw75kaO/ZzcN3PYmCu56xzvoX1GQ8YSquy195Ef6iI4fW/n21asDtmY8GvmPLQI2YFG1uG9YlhajTVyCpGj6IHqSO3w@KdI8UD09xzv93//wgN8PpTF1rjNIoy@Wg7OIXqFk1PGjwim34gO7bBbk5yKAEus3YLgOps5OsBxshvWCvKeg7ZDkRKyyAkqDAAwZWAYO5qE6gyUEhUcX981AGQ/vBmG@O/JDFXR5WzOYAOEREwtM7x6Dci@T4GCw4kiD2PF0XgP6dCVRzns6cyZxdK2vhRQtHf0OUhfBnqyKvnxa5AW/YqX3W7LzE/x@ywTLlUa798rcL2@PrAcith/TXW42KXgX9W3gXOgjHJ6NYbj5qPwwqT@BsnJxf2zZz8eJ41L9KsPbRrV5BylaAMX68U8fjo@@qT8MIORuacCvG8EdRC4EtSj/bUhwyoBd/ojiMT1wnQC0r8V1D3st6hqb/HuMDZzRNTYHpn9chxDrpF4naryqgFatnCR5fJPrbt7Emz1snxtDjUp/K@pA6PBDOG7TWxs@qhN@rK7qrIwr0hgLyw2@x7l0iOoGTgaqkZfcpZcgDXb5lqpihHBRZ1ajbynqPaIWte5j5dJqZ@K7MUTvhIkZHwJ4eCyo3c8eVmCwiccuq634VOrrG@p4GGq/flNhYzfHKuURlfkd3ogXCFiCremFFj/GNDe@wu@jIX4aX1J@3RyFbjZRxfKi96wHtSwKs0bZOoN3flq2SrJlN7KymiWRE7JSGceLlMvi9ThQgk0YqJs9iAAfIp@lvG6c8qqSty5YtP3H372yNzWheUZCP4PsbhJhNxVKx2l89ZLjLbH3ksTB3hbCAJ8T8KRYfd0j2ZWfu1PekgJGfXh7slP2E8rOLjwcoetfo4KfG6bGQIOTU1b6cmq8mHLxl4iXuxaHAu0rwohc@V4@hUTz2I9cyvoVixoaKElxWZSnMapPgxwQj6IzZDn95wLS0CCOL1gpgZT84@@8iwKTAAyohvECPWvrrWEkYHsma124POddALmhaVwukZHJYEMFcOQalJfy9wpxpw5r76QaURfNDUTDGxyve8dE3ScSNqWx12H5Y7nae//nj31jaH8loQ6JkY5ZPeOb@FR9bmZigyyWWHMKdcD6tAHTq1mJiNWZWB4LG6Cs37dUKq5wRMYxE9eiWRGy3inTO3rFmhWsIxWhi8CmJNROWQ6PCgPNm5h2VYaMKoQyST3OSRs79xRYAiPebSXYC8fCG7dUZ@QLmaKuqC4x2wY8cYYE2OsJ7VUeu1466G/oqGAB97KpNVs2O071zO502SilXozdwP7p4GqoZwuuDAazp0ZzBmyLU1j@TEfL2f/pzW1V6xpfvmTONRHFuWSxCkt8IZLq7dHB0f7xSe/kwzGwca6UDDwq29ysZeuULXzQ5SJbWGbJP@z2s44L69jjZga7yrdyaAeodcwGFuYMGNYqLI1royw79bqirP34sD8DZw1Ki01g1sQVFpTFZYtyIUUw0imvm6GYXuphtiyB8QhjtKIABIE1HstTMpQEQaFrpBdkoPWeB2IcXeeUl3y86l2WvmKFVB1teYoGEQVcm9kPW1Ug5SuIze4531xl6xjkbFO3d0D1f/71b7zDO8hh/J/leAzj/@bjUx259LAlyGlcsgbZ8vHgiGTgWvjBQ2e2diZez4J@RwWU/SFw8JIxBJdzYlfnXcGR@x@BnyAEYCaqKWomw0fToTzN8@SFrqMznsTBWGPVC52BHECxNUjY9V8KbLiDMenb7e0tE5Jjql4uALI@zgRTaQ5QUV4QkQiXfmKfj1zS6XSImEEuRu1tizNSrzqnLfF8SWgV1grcb/cJ7IEtqx0w1y23yVWnbiq4ldg2kUyJDC1wyVwuYNUyG8ASBV9HJT9EcBtxySrsRNBZTkCb0@tFPIJgAFVtiHxiP7ssAKkAiMNWROGB7gK9MMPyZf9OrNTWxSD@jMtYdv1C3KQ6BDTkfzZoTgTj/@Lj/sBQvw43/WSw1J3ew18G5Pt9fTwL2TuOYiyh3gKtRG7qzZZubitrdiKWoIBatIovABLsAOzKpf7nOMl6r/cPvj88On7Q2WYrpfvLJCJ1O/WBqjX6w@VA2qDzy4LgJL4Air/R4lVzXOHfrDd7/XI3dlKbXd2jlzp2nARNX8xAfJE7dyhWeDt67egLGkB/yzdVUwTkK4Su8CBlW6dmkdEvka7vfHjmhfsD/SkrWFBJ/FkRG4YQI3ygZO8HGkX0mshgXaEDSusUkPenSmPxu3Zj@UvE2kn@rSyI7@vcvnQbxGBZVd1i0ciag3qdD8ggH4wHEeqYda1/p2u6dStXA/taB7egdOXq1DbrrVq9Xo1qcjVCw3j2DIPYvAp2d6aJmjiDRWo1UCzw9mCndjWyqk5Hrnp2s8Z2wCPEh1vY8DXTtduqM9erz0DNG/AmpehNqFzNFMxYDE0z50Df59iPqnojdJJbWSTiDH/QQfRVv15HGrTqGRLwVR8c14FysJpjnYVNq3S3@iS0mFeS7irrr79WzG1CRHnebD3ZUwB4S9drl4M3e5bUd8ZN7Rd3KFUU0dwSrWhLqOi1c3J0cXT0FzCZpnIs9p/I3efkea1hbe/UGrDJbOz9CT7kSJLaLen4VPpFqHT/BGLstraf7MHgvHMuVDrDeqevddVhty9UboXKzVyoCBV71nlfx0//TbfOP/u9H@HaUYf95OjH/d7xfqPZUSvNN4eN5vGHVxUTHtrLJ5xqwdP7/d6bww8njSbf8ueDj/sfjt72Xvu@n2Sel3nxdNita6pKVI10h0DC7Gm9W7fzPCefzmqgdG@6sw@62gHUPwqV97hUVQeK1h1@ESr9Sh@4NW8agXFpzMyLwdbh9uGeefEuPlz9OzyEaX9mfI5TY2pMTc80zZlBPxjXM@PaCOND04M7hT8jhKFvjGfGxIiMyDTvwHn8X3gYvzuMAVQM2/KZkSNUYwz3yeHhOwA2BsSf4c83DMO8MI3LGdAbmOxzeqYYxta2vFPfLf/sJwpLVTrV@l5d3YOP3a13ytvLisf4pX0RpGQgQcZL@n1IIdLJZd8cYgiqiaZYI8OhxX6hYqbXNizMdMuHLWvsW3Tm55bEFVGW6aUTyGJzMGuO26ICAV7eVcBkzJaiqLKBAX9LOTU7HXm7rXS78nZTgWlRmolxKsm38q05V/DSlw1lqMxhNMBXUmVeQRcRka22AuGLKl9029SbW/ZMF87O3vROemdntllBQLouVDTrvWg2RQlPb2GaHAdUCyAmtHYFET4VWGSP6AQA4vIso/AJjxxaUHpVFFd0@XkNtdnnz05SA19haejams3dnfbObqu509jZ3dlqm9vtdsNsNsznO893jYZpmDvm9k5712zsbO22tra2dmG2vftcrwkVj44xiU9IBl4zHkuJpJovxdYOZLut56JQAc@KfcgOdmxjbdoVsNtOZKLoNR2NSTyviAOppt9ifQpOU7Hmek0Sz0UBoHe6t5Xt9hwPNBc87BJs7eJBwRbNeacLo6qE8CR8p7birbhSrVbBbt93xZZ4qAk2/ncY3IEcYjwCQJXsS9w2v0bfW5UXidTakgZ2hVcusvlcqXSbzzXI3CtD/lLegnfDClOPpomczXa@8yYTv/kdOf9iftmu6rokNduEmNvI0tOz07O/NIGlu7tic/tXXf9WzITZZdwYU3CpRbgpcPRS/52DeXO0DB4weFdAnFpymCCLA3@EPL7zjrN9/RX7bznwTkC6kH8yDsBM3AZL5kmNmcxQIbesUgA7knEWUgiTVyy8NsuLNCKGJfBF2Bu0lkPAghpBbFyALzFOyL5tWsTvIDC4Q3gpMeBnsaNu4zCgkcyo8IeKtVyzpKQLu9doWdtfr/Plc04WP48bevzYfG75COSF2Ghw5XK3cm8BFGmwRhoYUnnM33MMyITkJYQG@cPHuLcfIqmyOBMjYTVZvl@JYi7U8kZoCXjsWmIJP8iucosR3voaPnvmnib9cGgpoZ3jvV4PrblwIft8SS23Q1s1rQSItfJ@ve4P7VD5QU4Y8aFtwGLAjZAz5XYp6cguxZUpjZt@pH6Nho23/ahuDhtFo/bJvmk4ttGYwRfY1ggavwDzFqyUc/umHllOB76YbNzhRGJndce68wq3XMiBfdN3hrahWAFsrNffwmGAzqwf1OtDBZAHMPlwoxU8e@bUg@7MClRVwVWnrZdv@zkMhnUbn1/ITmf28qZfwP4XMtxtQBMoQDzsuysDgAf0WcBjLr4V6ZzGGZI3A/JC2659eln7VLOfPLnpz9Rw2ODsf2GsBI/Ez5D4dR2Ra5/WFYuxhDUeZPGp/@KpVsuI2ADtAyY3krWdnMLaJ5hJVtYw/z8)

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

Want to learn more? Try the [polygot chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)!

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .007665 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1275 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via comparing the tokens to a previous execution (EDIT by @ais523: and subsequently confirmed to work by running it locally).
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.

### Explanation

### Zsh

A couple weeks ago, after I spent some time trying to run the polyglot in various languages - just trying to find something that would stick. I pulled up Zsh and found it produced the same answer as Bash.

“That’s cool,” I said aloud to a room full of otherwise productive people, and wondered more silently if it was literally reading the Bash script. So I altered the bash and found Zsh was again mirrored Bash.

So what’s going on here? Zsh and Bash are two closely related shell scripting languages. They’re so close in fact that it was a bit of a chore to find differences. [Here](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells)’s the resource I found for finding those differences.

The first difference I attempted was a variable expansion that Zsh had but Bash did not. `${foo:u}`returns “FOO” in Zsh, but “foo” in Bash. And so a Zsh-Bash polyglot was born.

`a=a; if [[ ${a:u} == $a ]];then echo 50;else echo 54;fi;exit;`

Only problem, Japt hates me, but more specifically, it hates my use of curly braces. I’d been down the Japt path enough times to know I didn’t want to do it again. So I kept looking. `$#argv` returned the number of arguments in Zsh, where Bash did the same, with the string `argv` appended. Second try:

`if [[ 0 ==  $#argv ]];then echo 54;else echo 50;fi;exit;`

Well this one worked, for everything, except Brain-Flak. Brain-flak considers everything after the `#` as a comment. I didn’t want to move Brain-flak, nor did I want to redo it’s stack flipping jumbo in Octave’s space, so I went back to the drawing board. `$argv[1]` returned `[1]` in Bash and the value of argument 1 in Zsh. Third time’s the charm:

`if [[ $argv[1] == "[1]" ]];then echo 50;else echo 54;fi;exit;`

Well, Pyth and 05AB1E didn’t like the brackets outside of what they considered a string. But that was fixable. We’d just check if `$argv[1]`  contained a `1`. Boom:

`if [[ $argv[1] == *"1"* ]];then echo 50;else echo 54;fi;exit;`

Great Success!

### Alphuck

The `s` in `else` added another close bracket that needed a matching opening, so I added `p` here `'p\';` to counterbalance.

### Fission: defusing the bomb

You ever have a moment while coding something where the program inexplicably works as you’d expect? That’s kind what happened here.

I found the new Bash script shifted the scripting line into a position where the `D`’s in the INTERCAL line no longer lined up with commands on the scripting line that inflated atomic masses or output some undesired non-sense. At least this is my presumption because I put back the `__` in `R"12"__*` and it put the error code (that @ais523 introduced ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)) back at zero.

This is usually the point at which I throw a comment in my code to taunt my future self for having to debug my hack. But after chatting with @ais523 a bit we arrived at a solution that would be a more permanent fix.

Fission now ends in a different location from where its string is added to the stack with the purpose of terminating the program as quickly as possible – hopefully before any other atoms collide, split, or introduce bugs. The shortest time span where we can collapse the reaction and still produce a correct result is 3 tics. For example, if we add `Rx_*` to the polyglot, then it will synch up with `R"12` by hitting the `2` and the program ending `*` command simultaneously. The `_` here is to reduce the mass of the atom to zero since all atoms start with a mass of 1 and `*` outputs the colliding atom’s mass as it’s error code. The `x` is a space holding no-op here. I didn’t actually look up if `x` is a no-op, I’m just making conversation.

This gives us 1 character of flexibility to find a home in the polyglot and it turned out that adding  `Z_*` to Cardinal’s line was generally accepted. This atom starts at the `D` in  `#=x<R+++++[D` heading in the down direction.  The `Z` makes pointer turn left, which is fortunate because `Z` is ignored by Minimal-2D and Cardinal, both of which traverse this character location in their 2 dimensional code paths.

Good enough for fission.

### Cardinal

Cardinal had one wrinkle that had to be worked out with this Fission thing. The existing solution was 1 character too long to allow Fission to divert into a private code path, and the Fission snippet included `*` which is an addition operation for the tops of Cardinals two stacks. So I reworked the solution to end with the addition operation, which coincidentally is how an older version of cardinal used to work. New solution is:  `%++=ttt *.` (extraneous no-ops removed).

And here’s a breakdown of the logic:

> `++` Add primary stack up to 2 [2][0]
>
> `=` Copy active stack top value to secondary stack [2][2]
>
> `ttt` Multiply the tops of the stacks and push the result onto the active. Three times.  [4][2], [8][2],[16][2]
>
> `*` Add the stacks and push the result onto the active stack. [18][2]
>
> `.` Output active stack

### TRIGGERED

The `Z` in the new fission solution is the Trigger jump code, so we need a new, unused letter. Now it’s `X` initiated here:  `PkPPX`

### Incident Report

I honestly don’t know what happened here. I worked the Zsh version with curly braces, got to the point of balancing for Incident, and then realized a fatal bug. After reworking everything else, Incident just seems to work. All I can say for sure is I removed the `89` detokenizing string on the last line.

Edit: the Modular SNSUP change below tokenized `#<`, so I threw a space between `#` and `<`

### Modular SNSUP Edit

Thanks to @CalculatorFeline for pointing out that Modular SNSUP was broken!

The `$` in the Bash/Zsh section broke Modular SNSUP which starts are the first `$` encountered. I moved `<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.` to the line prior to it would continue to start at the correct place.

### Where to go from here

[This](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells) resource I found for Zsh has some other shell scripting languages with minor differences to Bash. My suspicion is that some of the other languages can be worked into the same space as Bash and Zsh without too much effort.

Good Luck

Comment: You seem to have accidentally put in two VIP scores.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks. fixed.

Comment: Does Modular SNUSP work?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Oops. Nope, it doesn't. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Chance Nope, you kept the old VIP score :P. I dropped in the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

## 58. [Ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/), 1288 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//`"`   ['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉( 1P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++  L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_00)
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ ']56pq[' ];#//
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)|/=1/24=x/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#*/{puts(p);}/*
#
/*
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#
#sss8␛dggi2␛`|$//''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X222999"26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTpLW9vKkuvoL5xNR3YiybZeNhBAlgNJyB3OOTkwgeTcL7YhstS2FfSKHmAgzjfbmW8Wd383s7z/427nV9w/cqaqW36ATZKzGwNyS11dVV1VXS/xRwU/5DgOrkdBnJOcZjnxUv@Sphp5cU32HD/bbLYEgUGlsVe4fjQi@ZgSP0qKnAz9gGaC6@SkQ5ISi4YDUiEpdTwOJgzjlOASEl4ExCdukpBB4Iw1lwQ@g83iEOdzmiYphWtGIko9kiXU9Ye@y@gQOslplPlxlGnEdy/IlR8ExKMBLFgQdxuAjBTZ0iNOShO8WCDwcZN7rM7vqhRgIjrbLk2clG03Jgnb@2zXV6mTJMCkUCEnwHjuhzQjfi5lhDqZjzKEJRmNPCapZC7dmDjR8i7Jpe8QB/gtUoY7o2kO29MYXjKmKQWUDhIfpU5I5KvUz0EEKMh9ckydlJymlCpABRRAM9dJgI87JIFYjBRy3IjGFNVuSwdHryVQGF@hOUkuVNLW6b//LDhEs0n13II/WxQt4eC3V@S22sMxcAHIQKlJKjsKsb@STO/1KPxNzIE@SqcCYBVAKgHR4yTXAbOT5sDeYqReNrUkWCJL2vc0sWREHMoDXZDDiLxvsH25RZpS4GIhUucCthzE0QikCVtNiwilEZEtAxTgxpGXNQi9BJnFEddQfMXkezr2QWUZKsQZgHgcFyXPDwATJxwBsLxSnjO6WRwUDA5WZjmaH8gEliLGwyF5T4aOH@ASmEdUnOuUZkWQ45oi8lDvoR9RTyMzNtzYQ6AwvgRyDiBlD@DMhEsnjTEFwKCGmG0Vp/71t797oxHg2XfdOPVKY31PvNgtQmDYYcw6YIhornHkBIwtgGsgdb4cCFw6ge85OZKPrksSjAlG9SouAo/EQDC98uFgjZ1LOIzDIXVzyk08LnLgsUFC54L7B5/bLWw8dAagWEaA0WbbVsneS9CSS7nBqGGRD7eJmhwQKdPP5Oe78vPHPQq8KZpSq@r6yAJr02rsEdxJ3zKc9/sLfaL1nPoxnqIgGRfgM2AmyhLwJikK03VgOxk6lRx8XoMMmKCZJwJDZ0f0ikopJQM417ONMRvhNoDrVTy3JYaFTmdwd02MeksWBtYJRpZnK04iiK@AMOMNHSfYdITEnZEDpPJyQ/t8Q5wie3J3axcRWDpiG1CyrQ580A7aAbiaUhlLewTwVpPDADauvaVDETrXgMXlLnqhSeIPQckh2G16TVyKhwFOBeV@DokUzDAyH@woHhJDbW5ufkf5earvqx90R73Rv6lj3Pw9Ne@TIb0igRONCmcEhhxHsMRxXZrk5QmCnWQ5nJH7bpA9VEufrmVjobp3nzbzbaW3X6KB3odrr/TQDpo9CCoEUasBnHLipCN2Eonnp3Beguv71AHg8h5x8SOC3GHgo/gAC7PABEZGJ9QtcjhuYMhXY98dg@0idxE/sNw73icPj5apg8tRh3PSyIzZedoUNH3@CNl4EIWKGl3FA14fUXXuPGDKX37wbcxOFq5BHM9ZBA@19FTTHQ1srxQaRPMTzCTA/c1CNztZ8/RiLk8Q8M8YmFL6uQCFgT37owhBnGge9pc8o59FEoQKP/NB6hjA0dZPD48wHvxOeQ4DcuexbNmZx5DRwPIyQOPETAkCdccxUSMilTzIIounn4AtPUtdNlCXkghR0UBOMsqLTc0QfeJ52f2ASjqrcIyk1CBdUew3IIYFGZhQVAQB3BQRO2IyVW7B1lyaZRocGJCthtkIcCfWqTK9C5iP0/iK0KliSevI/UmFvCwG/uT/oUZc5ItfYVdLamCPfkQPK4AzRYhiKboVCBDeYQSxBrzwDQsKETq5IiwCJ@d5gRsXIJm5ACFAOLbBZX4Ku/oVciXyq48hbAiZ1SLjZkn6BHPLniAm1/k4jlp3nZC4mGnyJO@9HkJM0pLr9eFXXEbFFrzxo4sYedPD2ejc0MzNOyigSFhdOfSzMbvcAV1ha3WGrc7CwZBd1gBEaDz3bJRNhHEUc@IgIT9y9LfsSwNHu46Du/7sDvkXFI7HiKo7LX3gR/qADh@CfP3ixSGDGQ4G/kNAIAYsg2bfa8DSYrBOSpDGjFfiHbkj59MizQPV03P8pv/7Hx7Ie1UbY@c6g8T3Yj44j@gVakYdPqiccinesMt6RX4qAiiKvoPDdTDZdYL5YD2uXfKWgrVDWhKxWgg4DQI4eiAycAmr5gwnISg8Ovtej5TJ8G7Y5KsjP1TBlrc0gykQbjEVwITsISz3Yj9HgzVCGsSOp/OqzacLjXLZ04kziqNrfSkIaOngB1idhWeyKNPycZEX/Iq12fd05yf4960jWEIam/svzIPy6wF4YGLrIdvlxyYF76K@DpwLfYDD8yEM12@Vbyb1R1AIzr4fAvv9JHFcql9l@LXWbN5AUhVAeX3y27uT42/aD0MI2VYa8OtadIeRC2Eoyr@PCXYZsMufMTxmB64TgPW1uO1hd0RdEpN/T7CBM7jGcn78520IqY7qdaLGi5pl0XxJkocXue76Rbw9w9a5MVSV9HtRB0KHH8J2m97S8EGb8GN1URll3JCGWAqu8T3OpUNUN3AyMI28lC69BG2wy7dMFSOEizazGH3LUO8xNatOHypwFisT340heidMzXgTwM1DQe1@9rBAg203dlksxbvSXl9Rx8NQ@/WbBhu7OdYVD5jMD3gjntJj0bRkF1r8kNDc@Ar/Hgzx4/iS8uv6KHSzlqsf8DZqwEwC0tLV5Z77PWv93c/A18BlvRe8WMcVT9fesmbWvLrMGmUPDp75adlzyeZtzcpilkROyGpuHM8yQYsX9iAg7OZAAe5BYHoX@Sx3duOUl6e8B8KSgH/@wyubXCOaZyT0M0g6RxG2ZaEGHcdXzzndkvp@kjjYJEMc4AoDnl2rL/dJduXn7pj3tkB/716fbpeNibJFDDfHGJGWuOD7hqkh8ODklNXQnBsvptwqS8LzVbNNwaEowohc@V4@hvz3xI9cyhofs2IcOEkRLMrTGK26QQ6JR9FHs@LgUwHZcRDHF6wmQU7@@Q/ejoFJQAZcw3hGnvUHlygSsCeT9UBcnorPkNzQNC5BZBQyHO0CJHINZ4ry5wpxxw7rE6UaUWddEiTDOyUv90@IekAk7G5j08Tyh3J1/@1f3neNvv2VhDrkazrWaUxu4hP1mZmJDTIDsaYUKrvlaQOmF7MSEasTsdwWdlJZ43BuVNzgiIxjpq5Z1yNkTVhmd/SKdT1YaytCz4XdTSjCshxuFYaad0PtqgyJXgj1lnqSk018BUBBJDDibVuCTXWs4HFJdUK@kDHaiuoSc9OAOy6QAJtGob1Ir5crGv0VHRQsD7hsas2WzbZTPbfbHTZKqRdjW7F71rvq69lMKr3e5InRnIDY4hTAn@p4cg5@e3Vb1TrGly@Zcw3V2VSyWKkm7oqkent8eHxwcrp/@u4ExDhVSgEel/1y1vt1yncBYMtFNjuZpfzwtQFr3bDWPy5muKt8Kcd2iFbHzsDsOAOFpcJP49Yoy069rihLbzEOJhBDwGixm8y6wcKMs7jsdc60CId0zAtwqMrndpjNa2ncwhBPUQCKwNKTpU8ZaoKg0jWyH2Rg9Z4Hahxc55RXorx8ntfQYoVUHW2@Cyh1BYTN7NWeF2j5ClIG9yNfXGVwDHO2rm3co/q//vZ33iru5TD@z3I8hPF/8/GZjlJa7S1yHueiQbG8PzwmGbgWvvHQmSztiZfZYN9RQYkfggQvmUAQnDO72O8Cj9x9D/IEJYAw0UzRMhk9mvblcZ4nu7qOzngUB0ONFVV0AnoAw9agjtA/F9i5h8Okb21ubZiQs1P1coaQNYRGmOFzhIqyS0QiXPqJ/XHgkna7TcQMUkRqb1lckHrVOWuJH@eMVgFW4H67S2ANLFmsgLlOuUyuOnVTwaXEtolkSqRvgUvmeoFTLbMBgCj4OCrlIYLbiEtRYW@JTnIC1pxez@IRBAMotkOUE3t/M0OkAiKOWxGFFdsFfmGGpfH@nVipLatB/B3BWNK/K64zHQIW8j9rLCeC8X/xcbdnqF/76949zG1nf/UVg3z/BQHuheydRDFWdq@BVyI39WZLN7eUpXMilqiAWzwVXwAlnAM4Vy71P8VJtv/y4PDno@OTlRY5g5Tug0lE6rTrPVVrdPvzgXTP5mciffFaP3nz4vVMkMtclVP3uVqH/D5jDxD7nZdMq6TYxAoh0/hRxItcbu1GFpneEuBLnuStUJWV22m33@70osoK@S/r3l9VtBq@soJRL2NvrySyxsHMi8LT@ALM4xuNeTVHCP9muUXvl6ux/93s6B691LFhK2j6bAaCudy@w63CXyJwGczIg58on1RNEeguaLnCSsa@zMisoJvTW165ut1ZmIFzWjYw4Ojje2Ds8EIs9oGTvV9oFNFrIoMXCx1wDk4BiXSqNGb/iNCYvzpa0ua/lf2Q@2f7QLoNYvBgVd1iUd@awjH@2CO9vDfsRXiWrWv9J13TrVu5GtjXOrhfpSNXx7ZZb9Xq9WpUk6sROqCnTzFZmFbBv51roiZOAEitBooFURX8oV2NrKrTlque3ayxFXALcfgWFnzNdO226kz16lNwJw14klL02lSuZgpmhoammVPg71PsR1W9ETrJrSwScYJv4JB81a/XkQeteo4MfNV7J3VmXL0TnaUnVhnW9FFoMe8v3bXRP/6omFuEiPK02Xq8pwDylq7XLnuvLKnrDJvaZ7d/fHF8/FepoojmhmhFG0JFrxlfnun6R3DyhHSlfvex3Hn2rNawtrZrjT1LMht75iPj0SPTVORmUzl5JJvkWJI2W9LJmfRZqHQegVZbW4/3Hn0UKvjzsQ2Ddr/e7modtd/pCpVboXIzxSl70n5bx0/3VafOP4T8Cte22u8mx78e7J8cNJpttdJ8ddRonrx7UTHhZnN@h1MtuHt7sP/q6N1po8mX/OXw/cG749f7L33fTzLPy7x43O/UNVUlqkY6/e7G0dbRnlCZPKl36nae5@TDeQ2M8VVn8k5X20D/V6HyFuFVtadonf4XodKtdEGK06YRGJfGxLwwL97ER4vfoyOY8CfGpzg1xsbY9EzTnBj0nXE9Ma6NMD4yPfim8GOEMPSN4cQYGZERmeYdPA//hkfxm6MYUMWwLJ8YOWI1hvA9Ojp6A8iGQPgT/PiGYQB/xuUEOA1M9jk7NwwFk8JJu1rfq6t78LE79Xb59bziMfFosFGhS6T@5lbyuYvhvaLrgiTLctKTLMd2LFYKVbF52TX79eqts1tM8VzXzJrCjuSmYVm1/XK8AeNyuG1ZNHNci0783JK4tcoyvXQCWTR7k@awKSqYbe1A7k3MlqLKBt5uKGdmuy1vbSqdzlZTiVNRmohxKt1O@Y98O23L7KPgj6Lgw/LaUXq3chtgAEhh93wBgEmVaQU9TUQ2NhXINqiysSVv13fKH/ux8kW3Tb25YU904fz81f7p/vm5bVaQOkikollvRbMpSihSC6ucOKBaACG9tSOI8EGx2QM6AgIInmUUPuGxQwtKr4riis4/L6G0/vTJSSBs6JaGHrPZ3Nne3N5pNbcb2zvbG5vm1uZmw2w2zGfbz3aMhmmY2@bW9uaO2dje2GltbGzswOzmzjO9JlQ8OsQaLCEZOON4KCWSaj4XW9tQrLSeiUIFHDZ2t9v4HiDWxh0B3@EQmSh6Ddis6bfYVpATxZoiNgEu7c4t7mAqeNhs2tjBncEBnrY7MKhKuF7CR2or3ogr1WoVzvrbjtgSjzTBxn@DwgUoESYTwFPJvsSb5tfoZ6uym0itDalnV3ihKZvPlEqn@UyDQqvS5w/lDXjWrzAbapoVFGW2/ZM3GvnNnz5@gQArSc1NQswtlN9Xtc1/23A5Oz87/2sThLmzIza3/tD1b8VfmJ0HoiEFH12E6yLRfuq/cbDgiebRCAZvCgh8c9kSFG7gD1C6d55xgS8/Yv@YBc8E5AslKeMADpfbYFUYqbGD1lfILSvx/CGRcRZyP5OXmryozos0IoYlcCDsNVvzIVBBWyA2AuBDDDyyb5sW8duIDL4hXpUU8DNbUbdxGNBIZlz4fcWaw8w56cDqJV6W1tfrHHzK2eL7cUOPb5vPzW@BvRA7RK5crlbuAUB1DTBSz5DKbf7INiCrkucYGuRPb@PeegjNymxPjIXFZPl8oYqpUMsboSXgtmuJJfwiu8otpgzW1/DpU/cs6YZ9SwntHL/r9dCaCheyz0FquR3aqmklwKyVd@t1v2@Hyi9ywpgPbQOAgTZizpTbuaYju1RXpjRuupH6Neo3XnejutlvFI3aB/um4dhGYwJ/ILZG0PgMwpuJUs7tm3pkOW34w@zljiQSO6s71p1HuORCDuybrtO3DcUKYGG9/ho2A3xm3aBe7ytAPIDJ1YVW8PSpUw86EytQVQWhzlrPX3dzGPTrNt7vyk578vymW8D6XRm@bSATKMA8rLurA8AH/FkgY66@BeucxwmyNwH2QtuufXhe@1CzHz@@6U7UsN/g4t81FopH5ifI/LKNyLUPy4bFRMI6RrL4xN99otUyIjbA@kDIjWRpJeew9gFmksVpmP4f)

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006601 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1355 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 by @ais523.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.

## Explanation

@ais523 mentioned in his dc post that his answer used the same technique that Lua typically uses in polyglots, and that Lua doesn’t have `#` comments. I had looked into Lua a while ago and gave up on it because I didn’t know this trick of declaring a literal list from the scripting languages perspective. Last I looked at Lua, I learned that its interpreter would skip the first line if it started with a `#`. So I looked into creating hole in line two to put Lua.

I succeeded in this endeavor, and pasted the dc line into line 2; thinking Lua and dc would ultimately both live there. Then I noticed something with Japt.

I had recently started paying attention to the JavaScript that was transpiled by Japt, as seen in [this utility](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/). Until @WheatWizard’s Japt explanation, I hadn’t been thinking of Japt as a transpiler, mostly because I don’t really know JavaScript any better than I do any other language in this polyglot; which is to say that only really know its basic syntax. So when I glanced at the JavaScript Transpolation it only registered in my front brain as an even bigger symbol-salad than the polyglot itself.

This transpolation revelation lead me to 2 epiphanies. First, Japt transpiles comments – which clarified a LOT of the behavior I had seen. I’ll come back to this in the Japt section. Second, and more importantly, when I pasted dc into line 2 (or more specifically, when I pasted `[']` into line 2), the majority of the polyglot got cut from the end of the JavaScript transpolation.

This told me that it might be possible to get Japt to stop giving us so many headaches when we use curly braces. (I have danced around Japt and curly braces in at least 3 previous answers.) And that in turn meant that Ksh could be differentiated from Zsh using the upper case [variable expansion](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#var-expansion) I played with in my Zsh answer.

### Ksh

The variable expansion `${a:u}` returns `A` in Zsh and `a` in both Ksh and Bash. 
Our existing shell script, when run in Ksh, returned the same answer as Zsh, so thanks to @whearwizard’s golf suggestion, we concatenated our existing case select argument `$argv[1]` with `${a:u}`, and created a third case which looks for `A` to differentiate Zsh and Ksh. (On my own I would have nested cases which is more verbose.)

We also have to assign the `a` variable with the `a` value, which is what’s happening at the beginning of this Bash/Ksh/Zsh polyglot.

`;a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;`

And the preceding string `'(p(\'` gets another `(` to balance out the `)` in the 3rd case definition.

That’s the easy part. Now how did we include it?

### Japt

I confirmed @ais523’s assertion that that there is a parser bug in that unmatched `[`’s will cause Japt not to parse the anything after the `[`. And according to @ETHproductions, this bug has possibly existed since he wrote the parser (late 2015 – early 2016). So, this “feature” is in bounds for this polyglot. So, how do we exploit it?

For starters the bracket has to be closed for other languages, but hidden from being closed for Japt. The technique that I stumbled into solved this right off the bat, uses `'` to take the next character as a string so `[']` opens the bracket, takes `]` as a string which is never transpiled to JavaScript.

Pip needed the backtic based string still, and that got moved to line 4 (more on that later). I believe Japt also still sees the backtic string, and considers every `]` therein to be part of the string and not a closing bracket. So, the only rule we have to follow is to not put 2 closing brackets between `[']` and the start of this string on line 4. Not a big cost.

Next, Japt’s existing answer (`1|6$`) has lived on the last line of the polyglot for as long as I remember, but now that we’re not transpiling past line 2, we need to move this. Currently, line 1 is dominated by C’s preprocessor directive syntax, not to mention all the 2D languages that have to traverse the space. All these competing needs mean that Japt must conclude on line 2 and line 2 must start with `#/*` in order to remain hidden from the scripters and to initiate C/C++ block comment. So that’s where we begin.

`#` tells Japt to take the ascii value of the next character: `/`. This instruction breaks up the block comment syntax which gets passed to JavaScript as `47*`. Since, 47 is prime and therefore not easily multiplied by some fractional x to arrive at 7, I chose to multiply by zero and then add in the 7. I pulled the same trick as found at in the prior answer to sum 0 and 7 like so: `#/*0|7`.

From here, it would be preferable to immediately go into our parsing error to hide the rest of the polyglot, but `#/*0|7 [']` transpiles to `47*0|7,`, and that comma make for an unexpected end of input error (if you run this as stand-alone), so we obfuscate the transpolation with a Javascript comment. Remember, this still means that the ['] is parsed and transpiled, but Javascript will choose not to act on it come run time, because it is in fact a comment.

So, `#/*0|7//[']` gives us everything we need to answer with Japt and effectively kill it. But as always the devil’s in the details.

### Pyth

Pyth is another language that attempts to parse the whole polyglot, even though we tell it to quit in line 1. For Pyth we hide the bulk of the polyglot in the double quote that starts on line 2 which we only occasionally dip out of for things like Python’s multi-line string decleration. Pyth didn’t like to parse the Japt bracket solution, so the `"` had to go before the brackets. But the brackets can’t exist from within a string from Japt’s perspective if we want to bug the parser. So, for Pyth, we add `` `"` `` which Japt sees a single character, backtic string, and Pyth sees a long double quote string.

### Pip

Pip similarly did not like the bracket attack, but Pip like Japt recognizes the backtic as a string declaration, so we had to go a different route. Currently line 1 is obscured form Pip by way of a double space, line comment immediately following the `16`, so we just do the same here prior to the Japt brackets then enter the backtic string as soon as Labrynth would allow.

### Underload/Trigger/Prelude/Whitespace/Whirl/Incident

With all the space being taken up by Pip/Pyth/Japt on line 2, and the rigid requirements of the the Befunges to align their line 2 code with their line 1 code paths, some stuff had to move out of the beginning of line 2. Trigger got moved to the end of the Pyth string in line 1 where the Pyth quit statement resides. Underload got moved for the same reason, landing back near its previous home, towards the end of line 2.

The 0 thrown into the beginning of line 2 caused one of Whirl’s IPs to spin CCW instead of CW. So I had to correct the spin and position later in line 2 with an extra `10111`. The order of these instructions remains, but the characters are not consecutively placed any longer because of Prelude and Incident. (you could maybe save a byte by refactoring the whirl/Incident/cow line, but ain't nobody got time for that.)

Incident didn’t like the Whirl fix because it caused `10` and `01` to become tokenized and then overlap with some business tokens on the incident line causing the lot of them to de-tokenize, so the whirl insert had to get chopped up. Also, Underload’s move caused some parenthetic reshuffling for Prelude.

All of these needs plus the flexibility of Whitespace caused line 2 to shake out to look like this:

```
#/*0|7//`"`['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q
```

### Brain-Flak/Classic & C/++ & Octave

Finally, with all the curly brace requirements of Japt removed, I looked back through the history for all the Japt appeasing moves that have taken place and undid them.

The Bran-Flak business string now looks like this:`{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())` requiring only a single backslash to appease only Thutu.

The C/C++ “puts” line now looks much more reasonable like this `#*/{puts(p);}/*`.

And finally, the Octave+(Brain-Flak's stack-shell-game) looks like this:

```
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
```

Oh, I also took the `@` out of line 1. I never knew why I needed it, and it seems I don't today. /shrug.

### Test Driver Changes

I added a few more special outputs for displaying an easier to read version of Brain-Flak, Whirl and BF/SMBF code. Enjoy.

I may have made a couple other tweaks to the driver/polyglot that I'll only remember come Monday, so I'll probably add a little more later. But this is all I got for today.

Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Very, very cool. It's awesome to see how far this has come already and imagine where it will go in the future :-) I find it impressive that changing the structure of the Japt code allowed for so much reduction in size. If it helps any, you can use a semicolon to safely separate the return value from the un-parsed array: `7;['] <whatever>` transpiles to just `7;` which returns `7` when evaluated.

Comment: Please use `<code>` tags instead of `\`` for `#/*0|7//\`"\`['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q`

Comment: @ETHproductions I actually tried `;` in that spot, but had some kind of problem. Don't remember what it was now though. I might poke at it again a bit later.

Comment: Btw I don't know if you want to golf this anymore but I am next to certain the  `#` at the end of the second to last line is unnecessary.

Comment: @WheatWizard You're totally right! I'll leave it for the next post. I kinda don't like to make golfing edits after posting an answer. I'm always feel like I'm creating version issues for someone else.

Answer (score 10):

## 59. [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), 1324 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//`"`   ['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++  L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_00)
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#//
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9 or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(( {}){})>)}{}({}())'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"|/=1/24=x'/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log +39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#*/{puts(p);}/* 
#
/*
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#
#sss8␛dggi2␛`|$//''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X2229996
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. Note also that the line `#*/{puts(p);}/*`  has a trailing space. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkmfjF@qSBlkGQBIbKcqSQNCSbblHVeWSxpJd/UzSMggkSVjYjEWiJNNvrjNvDn3vyxz7P/o6X9E/UhORCS4SKbvqNqQFJpCREZERkbHBv1fwQ07i4HocxDnJaZYTL/UvaaqR59dk3/GzdrMlCAwqjb3C9aMxySeU@FFS5GTkBzQTXCcnXZKUWDQckApJqeNxMGEUpwSXkPAiID5xk4QMA2eiuSTwGWwWhzif0zRJKVwzElHqkSyhrj/yXUaH0GlOo8yPo0wjvntBrvwgIB4NYMGSuNsAZKTIVh5xUprgxQKBj5vcY3VxV6UAE9H5dmnipGy7MUnY3ue7vkqdJAEmhQo5BcZzP6QZ8XMpI9TJfJQhLMlo5DFJJQvpxsSJVndJLn2HOMBvkTLcGU1z2J7G8JIJTSmgdJD4OHVCIl@lfg4iQEEekBPqpOQspVQBKqAAmrlOAnzcIQnEYqSQ40Y0pqhORzo8fiWBwvgKzUlyoZK2zv79J8Ehmk2q5xb82aJoCYe/viS31T6OgQtABkpNUtlRiP2VZHq/T@Fvag71cToTAKsAUgmIHie5DpidNAf2liP1sqklwQpZ0rmniRUj4lAe6IIcReRdg@3LLdKUAhdLkToXsOUgjsYgTdhqWkQojYhsG6AAN468rEHoJcgsjriG4ism37OJDyrLUCHOEMTjuCh5fgCYOOEIgOWV8pzTzeKgYHCwMsvR/EAmsBQxHo3IOzJy/ACXwDyi4lynNCuCHNcUkYd6D/2IehqZs@HGHgKF8SWQcwApewBnJlw5aYwpAAY1xGyrOPWvv/3dG48Bz4HrxqlXGus74sVuEQLDDmPWAUNEc40jJ2BsAVwDqfPlQODSCXzPyZF8dF2SYEwwqldxEXgkBoLplQ8Ha@JcwmEcjaibU27icZEDjw0SOhfcP/jcbmHjoTMExTICjDbbtkr2X4CWXMoNRg2LfLRD1OSQSJn@QX62Jz973KfAm6Iptaqujy2wNq3GHsGd9C3DeXew1Cdaz5kf4ykKkkkBPgNmoiwBb5KiMF0HtpOhU8nB5zXIkAmaeSIwdHZEr6iUUjKEcz3fGLMRbgO4XsVzW2JY6nQOd9fEqLdiYWCdYGR5tuYkgvgKCDPe0HGCTUdI3Bk7QCovN3TAN8Qpsid3t3YRgaUjtiElO@rQB@2gHYCrKZWxskcAbzU5DGDj2ls5FKFzDVhc7qKXmiT@CJQcgt2m18SleBjgVFDu55BIwQwj88GO4hEx1Ga7/R3l56l@oL7XHfVG/6aOcfP31HxARvSKBE40LpwxGHIcwRLHdWmSlycIdpLlcEbuu0H2UC19upZNhOr@fdrMt5XefoUGeh@uvdJDO2j2IKgQRK0GcMqJk47ZSSSen8J5Ca7vUweAy3vExY8IcoeBj@IDLMwDExgZnVK3yOG4gSFfTXx3AraL3EX8wHLveJ88PFqlDi5HHS1IIzNm90lT0PTFI2TjQRQqanQdD3h9RNW984Apf/XBtzE7WbgBcbxgETzUylNNdzSwvVJoEM1PMZMA9zcP3exkLdKLhTxBwD9hYErp5wIUBvbsjyMEcaJF2F/xjH4WSRAq/MwHqWMAR1s/OzrGePAb5TkMyJ3HslVnHkNGA8vLAI0TcyUI1J3ERI2IVPIgiyyefgK29Cx12UBdSSJERQM5ySgvNjVH9InnZfcDKumuwzGSUoP0RHHQgBgWZGBCUREEcFNE7IjJVLkFW3NplmlwYEC2GmYjwJ1Yp8rsLmA@SeMrQmeKJW0i9ycV8qIY@tP/hxpxkS9@hV2tqIE9@iN6WAOcK0IUS9GtQYDwjiKINeCFb1hQiNDJFWERODnPC9y4AMksBAgBwrENLvMz2NUvkCuRX3wMYSPIrJYZN0vSp5hb9gUxuc4ncdS664TE5UyTJ3nv9BBikpZcbw6/4ioqtuC1H13EyJsezkfnhma276CAImF95cjPJuxyB3SNrfUZtjoLhyN22QAQofHcs1E2EcZRzImDhPzI0d@wHw0c7SYO7vqzO@SfUzgeY6rutvShH@lDOnoI8tXz50cMZjQc@g8BgRiwDJr/bgBLi@EmKUEaM1mLd@SOnM@KNA9UT8/xl/7vf3gg73VtTJzrDBLfi8XgPKJXqBl19KByyqV4wy6bFfmpCKAo@g4O18Fk1wkWg8249sgbCtYOaUnEaiHgNAjg6IHIwCWsmzOchKDw6Px3M1Imw7thk6@O/FAFW97WDKZAuMVUABOyh7Dci/0cDdYIaRA7ns6rNp8uNcplT6fOOI6u9ZUgoKXDP8DqPDyTZZmWT4q84Feszb6nOz/Bv28dwRLSaB88Nw/LnwfggYnth2yXH5sUvIv6KnAu9CEOz0cw3LxVvpnUH0MhOP99COy308RxqX6V4c9Gs3kNSVUA5fXpr29PT75pPwwhZFtpwK8b0R1FLoShKP8@JthlwC5/xvCYHbhOANbX4raH3RF1RUz@PcEGzvAay/nJn7chpDqu14kaL2uWZfMlSR5e5LqbF/H2DFvnxlBV0u9FHQgdfgjbbXorwwdtwo/VZWWUcUMaYSm4wfc4lw5R3cDJwDTyUrr0ErTBLt8yVYwQLtrMcvQtQ73H1Lw6fajAWa5MfDeG6J0wNeNNADcPBbX72cMSDbbd2GW5FO9Ke31JHQ9D7ddvGmzs5lhXPGAyf8Ab8ZQei6YVu9Dih4Tmxlf492CIn8SXlF83R6GbjVz9AW@jBswkIC1dX@6537PW3/wMfA1cNnvBi41c5W6w6TnL4t6wHtei6MwaZWsOnvlp2YrJFt3OynKWRE7ISnEczxNEi9f7IDds8kBd7kG8ehv5LKV245RXrbw1wnKDf/7DK3tfY5pnJPQzyEXHEXZroTSdxFfPON2S@kGSONg7QxzgIQOedKsvDkh25efuhLe8QK1vX53tlP2KsnMMNycYqFa44PuGqRHw4OSUldacGy@m3FhLwotV803BWSnCiFz5Xj6BtPjUj1zK@iHzGh04SREsytMYjb1BjohH0XWzmuFTAUlzEMcXrFRBTv75D96lgUlABlzDeE6etQ1XKBIwM5O1Rlyeoc@R3NA0LkFkFDKc@AIkcg1HjfLnCnEnDmsfpRpR580TJMMbKC8OTol6SCRsemMvxfJHcvXgzV/e9YyB/ZWEOqRxOpZvTG7ij@pTMxMbZA5izSgUfKvTBkwvZyUiVqdiuS1ssLJ@4sKouMERGcdMXfNmSMh6s8zu6BVrhrCOV4QODZueUJtlOdwqDDVvktpVGfK/EMow9TQnbXwzQEEkMOLdXIK9dizscUl1Sr6QCdqK6hKzbcAdF0iAvaTQXmbdq4WO/pIOC5YeXDa1Zstm26me250uG6XUi7Hb2PvQvxro2Vwq/f70R6M5BbHFKYA/0fHkHP768raqdY0vXzLnGoq2mWSxCk7cE0n19uTo5PD07ODs7SmIcaaUAjwp2@isJeyUrwjAlotsfjJL@eHbBNbRYW8EcDHDXeVLObYjtDp2BubHGSis1IMat0ZZdup1RVl5uXE4hdACRotNZtYkFuacxWULdK5FOKQTXpdDsb6ww2xRYuMWRniKAlAEVqQsq8pQEwSVrpGDIAOr9zxQ4/A6p7xA5VX1orQWK6TqaItdQAUsIGxmr7fCQMtXkEm4H/niKoNjmLNN3eQ@1f/1t7/zDnI/h/F/luMRjP@bjz/oKKX1liPncSEaFMu7oxOSgWvhGw@d6cqeePUN9h0VlPghSPCSCQTBObPL/S7xyL13IE9QAggTzRQtk9Gj6UCe5Hmyp@vojMdxMNJYrUWnoAcwbA3KC/1zgQ19OEz6dnt7y4RUnqqXc4SsTzTGxJ8jVJQ9IhLh0k/sj0OXdDodImaQOVJ72@KC1KvOh5b4ccFoFWAF7rd7BNbAkuUKmOuWy@SqUzcVXEpsm0imRAYWuGSuFzjVMhsAiIKPo1IeIriNuBQVtpzoNCdgzen1PB5BMIAaPEQ5sdc6c0QqIOK4FVFYs13gF2ZYdu/fiZXaqhrE3xCM1QJ74ibTIWAh/7PBciIY/xcf9/qG@nWw6ZXEwnYO1t88yPffG@BeyP5pFGPB9wp4JXJTb7Z0c1tZOSdiiQq4xVPxBVDCOYBz5VL/U5xkBy8Oj346Pjld65wzSOk@mESkbqfeV7VGb7AYSPdsfi7S56/009fPX80FucpVOXWfq03I7zP2ALHfeCW1TopNrBEyjT@KeJnibdzIMgFcAXzBc781qrJyO@sNOt1@VFkj/2XTa62KVsM3WTDqZ@yllkQ2OJhFrXgWX4B5fKNfr@YI4d@sdu79cjW2xZtd3aOXOvZxBU2fz0Awlzt3uFX4uwUugzl58BPlk6opAt0lLVdYS@RXGZnXeQt6qyvXtzsPM3BOy74GHH18PYyNX4jFPnCy/zONInpNZPBioQPOwSkgv06Vxvz/JzQWb5RWtPlvZZvk/tk@lG6DGDxYVbdY1LdmcIw/9kk/74/6EZ5l61r/Qdd061auBva1Du5X6crViW3WW7V6vRrV5GqEDujJE0wWZlXwb@eaqIlTAFKrgWJBVAV/aFcjq@p05KpnN2tsBdxCHL6FBV8zXbutOjO9@gTcSQOepBS9NpWrmYKZoaFp5gz4@xT7UVVvhE5yK4tEnOKLOSRf9et15EGrniMDX/X@aZ0ZV/9UZ@mJVYY1fRxazPtLd230998r5jYhojxrth7vK4C8peu1y/5LS@o5o6b22R2cXJyc/FWqKKK5JVrRllDRa8aXp7r@EZw8IT1p0Hssd58@rTWs7Z1aY9@SzMa@@ch49Mg0FbnZVE4fySY5kaR2Szr9IH0WKt1HoNXW9uP9Rx@FCn4/dmDQGdQ7Pa2rDro9oXIrVG5mOGVPO2/q@Om97Nb5h5Bf4NpRB73k5JfDg9PDRrOjVpovjxvN07fPKybctBd3ONWCuzeHBy@P3541mnzJX47eHb49eXXwwvf9JPO8zIsng25dU1WiaqQ76G0dbx/vC5Xpj/Vu3c7znLw/r4ExvuxO3@pqB@j/IlTeILyq9hWtO/giVHqVHkhx1jQC49KYmhfmxev4ePnv@Bgm/KnxKU6NiTExPdM0pwZ9a1xPjWsjjI9ND34pfI0Qhr4xmhpjIzIi07yD5@F/4XH8@jgGVDEsy6dGjliNEfyOj49fA7IREP4EX98wDODPuJwCp4HJPh/ODUPBpHDaqdb36@o@fOxuvVP@PKt4TDwabFToEXHQ3k6a2597WGSS9u6gR6d@PhBJQ@r3MOhXdF2QZFlO@pLl2I7FCqQqdjp75qBevXX2ihme9ppZU9hBbRuWVTsox1swLoc7lkUzx7UQvyVxG5ZleukEsmj2p81RU1QwB9uFjJyYLUWVDbzdUj6YnY683Va63e2mEqeiNBXjVLqd8a98O@vI7KPgV1HwYXntKv1buQMwMoE79oCvADipMqugA4rIVluBJIQqW9vyTn23/NqPFUApSi0Fv@IX3Tb15pY9lXTh/PzlwdnB@bltVpAXkE9Fs96IZlOUUOwWVkJxQLUAwn69tSuI8EEp2kM6BnIIn2UUPuGJQwtKr4riii4@L6D@/vTJSSC26JaGbrXZ3N1p7@y2mjuNnd2drba53W43zGbDfLrzdNdomIa5Y27vtHfNxs7Wbmtra2sXZtu7T/WaUPHoCAu1hGTgseORlEiq@Uxs7UBF03oqChXw6tgZ7@A7hFibdAV8/0Nkoug1YLOm36JZyIlizfQaAYMBnJ3uLW5hJnjYqdraxa3BMZ91ujCoSohAwkdqK96KK9VqFTzCm67YEo81wcb/Q4ULUCRMKICnkn2J2@bX6CerspdIrS2pb1d4OSqbT5VKt/lUg3KsMuAP5S14Nqgwm2qaFZRltvODNx77zR8@foEwLEnNNiHmNgrwq9rh/zpw@XD@4fyvTZDm7u7277r@rRgNs4tgNaLgx4twU7Q6SP3XDhZF0SJiweB1AcFxIVqCsg38IQr3zjMu79VH7P90wTMB@UI5yjiAo@Y2WKVGauzYDRRyy8pAf0RknIX80OTlKC@88yKNiGEJHAjb1NZiCFTQFIiNAPgQg5Ps26ZF/A4ig1@IaSUF/MxX1G0cBjSSGRf@QLEWMAtOurB6hZeV9fU6B59xtvh@3NDj2@Zzi1tgL8QukiuXq5V7AFCBA4zUN6Rym39kG5B5yQsMDfKnt3FvPYRvZb4nxsJysny@VMVMqOWN0BJw27XEEn6WXeUW0wrra/jkifsh6YUDSwntHH/r9dCaCReyz0FquR3aqmklwKyV9@p1f2CHys9ywpgPbQOAgTZizpTbhaYju1RXpjRuepH6NRo0XvWiujloFI3ae/um4dhGYwp/ILZG0PgMwpuLUs7tm3pkOR34wwznjiQSO6s71p1HuORCDuybnjOwDcUKYGG9/go2A3xmvaBeHyhAPIDJ9YVW8OSJUw@6UytQVQWhPrSeverlMBjUbbzfk53O9NlNr4D1ezL82kAmUIB5WHdXB4AP@LNAxlx9S9Y5j1NkbwrshbZde/@s9r5mP35805uq4aDBxb9nLBWPzE@R@VUbkWvvVw2LiYR1lWTxR3/vR62WEbEB1gdCbiQrKzmHtfcwkyxPw@z/AA)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006446 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1392 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was tested to output 33 on my own computer, locally, using the official interpreter.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 on my own computer, locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.

### Explanation

#### Tcl

Tcl is a language designed for embedding scripts into larger programs. This means that there are a lot of different dialects of Tcl with different commands; however, this particular program restrains itself to "portable" Tcl, running no commands other than ones with a common meaning on every platform. (The interpreter I used for testing is `tclsh`, which seems to interprets unknown commands as shell commands, although it isn't documented to do so.)

In this particular program, we mostly care about its bizarre parsing rules:

- If a token *starts with* `#`, it's a comment that lasts to a newline (thus `#…\n` is a comment, but `x#…\n` isn't;
- Most tokens are whitespace-delimited;
- If a token *starts with* `{` or `"`, it instead ends at the matching `"` or `}`;
- `[…]` substitutes the result of a command into a token (like `$(…)` in bash), *even if* it's `"…"`-quoted (but not if it's `{…}`-quoted).

The program is thus almost very simple; all we have to do is create a `"…"` string literal that most languages will ignore, and drop some Tcl code in square brackets into the middle of it. In this case, that's `[puts 59;exit]`. However, there are some problems with this method, each of which caused a clash with a different language. As such, they'll be discussed below.

#### dc

Polyglotting Tcl and dc is fairly difficult, because both of them complain upon seeing an invalid command, and very few commands are valid in both. We can't start a Tcl string literal with `{` or `"` because dc will complain about both. As such, we have to start with dc code.

One possibility is to just write the dc commands outright. We can actually almost pull this off directly:

```
c56pq="[puts 59;exit]";
```

This is a valid command in the shells and in most of the scripting languages, meaning that it's almost a very simple problem to our solution. However, it isn't valid Perl (variable names in Perl start with punctuation marks, normally `$`), and I couldn't find a way to make it valid Perl without breaking a lot more. So that was something of a dead end.

The other alternative is to hide code from dc using square brackets to quote it, along these lines:

```
[ "[puts 59;exit]" ,']56pq[' ];#//
```

That approach seems more promising, and doesn't conflict with any of the scripting languages. (Note the space after the second `"`; that's for Tcl, which requires whitespace between tokens.) The shells complain, but it's a warning rather than an error (they keep executing), so we can live with this for now.

#### Brain-Flak Classic

There are no changes to the Brain-Flak Classic code in this polyglot. However, it's mostly relevant because of what it prevents us from doing: it doesn't let us nest square brackets, `[…[…]…]`, without producing unwanted output.

As such, our dc/Tcl polyglot is going to have to work without nesting brackets, meaning that our double-quoted string literal is going to have to contain an `]` before the first `[` (as it's inside square brackets itself). Perhaps surprisingly, Tcl is just fine with this; it treats `[` specially, but `]` isn't special except to match a `[`. Of course, that means we're going to have to somehow add an extra `[` to the program in a way Tcl couldn't see, so that brackets stayed matched after we added an extra closing `]` for Tcl (to replace the `]` it couldn't see). I tried a ton of approaches for this, most of which ended up breaking some language or another (at one point I even managed to break Nim, of all things).

Eventually, I realised that you could make use of Tcl's weird comment syntax to hide a `[` from Tcl but not anything else, so I added an extra couple of lines to the program for that purpose (as Tcl comments end at newlines). It was complex, though (placement is very hard, as Tcl panics upon seeing `""""`, leaving only a small window where it could be placed, but you can fit it in *just* before the `""""` line by using single quotes to hide the whole thing from Python). Eventually, I came across the (apparently undocumented?) fact that `\[` also hides the opening square bracket from Tcl, which made things much easier.

#### Pyth

Adding double quotes to the program is inevitably going to cause trouble with Pyth, which hides much of the program inside them (although less of the program than you might expect). The basic issue here is that Pyth, despite being a golfing language, has a distinction between expressions and statements (which is inherited from the fact that it compiles to Python); place a statement inside an expression and the program won't compile. `#`, which is all over the place in this program (and many copies of which actually run in Pyth) is a statement, typically meaning "loop until an exception occurs" (it's overloaded and can also mean other things, but that's the most common meaning). It uses prefix syntax and single-character commands, so apparently innocent things like our `puts` can end up opening a lot of nesting levels, which all have to be closed before the next `#`-that's-parsed is seen. However, *until* the next statement that's parsed, we can happily expose fairly large chunks of the program to the Pyth parser; most things are expressions, after all.

The first change we need to make to our Tcl code, which is necessarily exposed to Pyth with this way of doing things, is to remove the semicolon (which I haven't been able to figure out the exact parsing rules of, but it's statement-like and normally crashes the parser if it appears in the wrong place). We can do that via using two substitutions rather than one, `[puts 59][exit]` rather than `[puts 59;exit]`.

The second change we need to make the polyglot work again in Pyth is to end the expression before the next statement occurs. As a prefix language, most of the time we can escape one nesting level via adding a literal (such as a number, or a string); that's how prefix languages work. It turns out that there are plenty of Pyth literals in the parsed area, so many of the levels close themselves naturally.

However, Pyth also has some variable-arity commands, which will consume arbitrarily many literals, and thus need to be closed explicitly. The command to do this is `)`, which is unfortunately one of the hardest characters to fit into the polyglot (especially as `(` is a variable-arity command in its own right). Still, I perservered with this approach, adding `")3)3)"` (i.e. dropping out of the Pyth string literal, cleaning up our expression, and going back into the literal), and Pyth started working. Of course, that broke a lot of other languages, and I'll be discussing those later.

I made heavy use of [this Pyth debugger](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) while working on the program; check the "Debug on?" box, and you'll see the Python that the program transpiles to. This is very helpful in knowing whether a syntax error is in the original Pyth or the output Python, and getting clues in how to fix it (e.g. if a Python statement has been placed in the middle of an expression, you know you'll need to escape some of the expression's nesting levels).

#### 05AB1E

There are two languages which hide most of the code in strings. One of them was Pyth, but the other is 05AB1E.

Luckily, 05AB1E is much better-behaved than Pyth, and will happily tolerate almost any character in parsed code. The character that causes the problems is the `q` in the dc code, which prints the top of the stack and exits the program, meaning it never reaches the `26` at the end of the program.

Well, this seems more like an opportunity than a problem, given that 05AB1E's accidental new behaviour is very close to the behaviour we'd actually want. A quick change of `56pq` to `56p26q` and we have a clean dc/05AB1E parallel-code (i.e. all commands executed in both) polyglot that  halts the parser for the rest of the code, and dc and 05AB1E naturally end up in the same place (but for different reasons). This also means that the 05AB1E code at the end of the polyglot could safely be removed, simplifying it a bit. (This may open up new opportunities for anything that cares about the end of the program.)

#### Underload

I added a lot of closing parentheses to the program to keep Pyth happy. Obviously, Underload likes its parentheses matched. This was a trivial fix; just add some opening parentheses just before the double quote before the Pyth code, and Pyth won't be able to see them but Underload will.

#### Prelude

Of course, all this addition of parentheses is something that can easily course major problems with Prelude. This is what determined *where* I added the Pyth/Underload code: just before the Thutu, at the end of the longest line of the program (just after the Prelude runs). Because it's on such a long line, the new parentheses don't vertically align with anything; and the `)(…)` acts as a Prelude comment (for exactly the same reason that `][…]` acts as a comment in brainfuck/SMBF).

#### bash/zsh/ksh

The Pyth/Underload addition adds a double quote to the program, in a section of the code which uses double quotes to hide code from the shells.  This is easier to fix than it seems; just add `'3` just after the opening double quote (the extra `3` is to close the nesting level that the `'` opens in Pyth), and `'` near the end of the Thutu code, meaning that we can actually end the parse in these languages a line earlier than we previously were. Some proportion of the `"'x"` on the line afterwards can likely now be golfed off (perhaps even the whole thing!), but I don't really want to mess about more with this now that it's working.

#### Incident

I needed to detokenise three tokens to balance the code. Coffeescript's `39` became `+39` to break up  `3`, a space was dropped into the Brain-Flak to break up `({}`, and a trailing space was added to the C (specifically, `#*/{puts(p);}/*` ) to break up the token consisting of `/*` and a newline.

### Future prospects

The end of the code is now much more open than it previously was. I don't know which languages care about that, but if you can think of one, now is a good opportunity.

Tcl shouldn't cause problems past the first non-`#` line, as all previous lines are commented out, and the parser exits before parsing any more.

Double quotes are now more usable than they previously were, because both Pyth and 05AB1E have had changes to make them more tolerant of double quotes in the code. (The `((("'3)3)3)` can easily be expanded if needed to close more levels of Pyth code, without negatively affecting anything else.) This probably increases the scope for adding more `#`-comment languages that don't have usable block comments.

Comment: I told Chance this but the `#` at the end of the second to last line is totally unnecessary.  I put it in earlier (it was needed then) but it can be removed now.

Comment: There's likely a lot of unnecessary code here; for example, the `#\n#\n` is very suspicious. I guess some time, someone's going to go round and golf it all off. (Perhaps while adding a particularly verbose language, to save VIP headroom.)

Comment: actually, #\n#\n is for labyrinth. I forgot to document that one in my last Japt refactor.

Answer (score 10):

## 60. [Moorhens 2.0](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24), 1423 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//`"`   ['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1␉0␉␉11)(22)S␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++  L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_00)
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#//
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)\{(<{}(( {}){})>)}{}({}()) li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"|/=1/24=x'/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log +39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#*/{puts(p);}/* 
#
/*
<>{//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax
#sss8␛dggi2␛`|$//''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X2229996
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkmfjF/qSBlkGQBIbKcqSQNCSbblHVeWSxpJd/UzSMggkSVjYjEWiJNNvrjNvDn3vyxz7P/o6X9E/UhORCS4SKbvq0O8NJYEJZGREZERkbNBvFfyQkzi4HgdxTnKa5cRL/UuaauT5Ndl3/KzdbAkCg0pjr3D9aEzyCSV@lBQ5GfkBzQTXyUmXJCUWDQekQlLqeBxMGMUpwSUkvAiIT9wkIcPAmWguCXwGm8Uhzuc0TVIK14xElHokS6jrj3yX0SF0mtMo8@Mo04jvXpArPwiIRwNYsCTuNgAZKbKVR5yUJnixQODjJvdYXdxVKcBEdL5dmjgp225MErb3@a6vUidJgEmhQk6B8dwPaUb8XMoIdTIfZQhLMhp5TFLJQroxcaLVXZJL3yEO8FukDHdG0xy2pzG8ZEJTCigdJD5OnZDIV6mfgwhQkAfkhDopOUspVYAKKIBmrpMAH3dIArEYKeS4EY0pqtORDo9fSaAwvkJzklyopK2zf/9RcIhmk@q5BX@2KFrC4S8vyW21j2PgApCBUpNUdhRifyWZ3u9T@JuaQ32czgTAKoBUAqLHSa4DZifNgb3lSL1sakmwQpZ07mlixYg4lAe6IEcReddg@3KLNKXAxVKkzgVsOYijMUgTtpoWEUojItsGKMCNIy9rEHoJMosjrqH4isn3bOKDyjJUiDME8TguSp4fACZOOAJgeaU853SzOCgYHKzMcjQ/kAksRYxHI/KOjBw/wCUwj6g41ynNiiDHNUXkod5DP6KeRuZsuLGHQGF8CeQcQMoewJkJV04aYwqAQQ0x2ypO/fOvf/PGY8Bz4Lpx6pXG@o54sVuEwLDDmHXAENFc48gJGFsA10DqfDkQuHQC33NyJB9dlyQYE4zqVVwEHomBYHrlw8GaOJdwGEcj6uaUm3hc5MBjg4TOBfcPPrdb2HjoDEGxjACjzbatkv0XoCWXcoNRwyIf7RA1OSRSpn@Qn@3Jzx73KfCmaEqtqutjC6xNq7FHcCd9y3DeHSz1idZz5sd4ioJkUoDPgJkoS8CbpChM14HtZOhUcvB5DTJkgmaeCAydHdErKqWUDOFczzfGbITbAK5X8dyWGJY6ncPdNTHqrVgYWCcYWZ6tOYkgvgLCjDd0nGDTERJ3xg6QyssNHfANcYrsyd2tXURg6YhtSMmOOvRBO2gH4GpKZazsEcBbTQ4D2Lj2Vg5F6FwDFpe76KUmiT8CJYdgt@k1cSkeBjgVlPs5JFIww8h8sKN4RAy12W5/R/l5qh@o73VHvdG/qWPc/D01H5ARvSKBE40LZwyGHEewxHFdmuTlCYKdZDmckftukD1US5@uZROhun@fNvNtpbdfoYHeh2uv9NAOmj0IKgRRqwGccuKkY3YSieencF6C6/vUAeDyHnHxI4LcYeCj@AAL88AERkan1C1yOG5gyFcT352A7SJ3ET@w3DveJw@PVqmDy1FHC9LIjNl90hQ0ffEI2XgQhYoaXccDXh9Rde88YMpfffBtzE4WbkAcL1gED7XyVNMdDWyvFBpE81PMJMD9zUM3O1mL9GIhTxDwjxiYUvq5AIWBPfvjCEGcaBH2Vzyjn0UShAo/80HqGMDR1s@OjjEe/Ep5DgNy57Fs1ZnHkNHA8jJA48RcCQJ1JzFRIyKVPMgii6efgC09S102UFeSCFHRQE4yyotNzRF94nnZ/YBKuutwjKTUID1RHDQghgUZmFBUBAHcFBE7YjJVbsHWXJplGhwYkK2G2QhwJ9apMrsLmE/S@IrQmWJJm8j9QYW8KIb@9P@hRlzki19hVytqYI9@jx7WAOeKEMVSdGsQILyjCGINeOEbFhQidHJFWAROzvMCNy5AMgsBQoBwbIPL/Ax29TPkSuRnH0PYCDKrZcbNkvQp5pZ9QUyu80kcte46IXE50@RJ3js9hJikJdebw6@4iooteO1HFzHypofz0bmhme07KKBIWF858rMJu9wBXWNrfYatzsLhiF02AERoPPdslE2EcRRz4iAhP3L0N@xLA0e7iYO7/uwO@ecUjseYqrstfehH@pCOHoJ89fz5EYMZDYf@Q0AgBiyD5t8bwNJiuElKkMZM1uIduSPnsyLNA9XTc/ym//sfHsh7XRsT5zqDxPdiMTiP6BVqRh09qJxyKd6wy2ZFfioCKIq@g8N1MNl1gsVgM6498oaCtUNaErFaCDgNAjh6IDJwCevmDCchKDw6/96MlMnwbtjkqyM/VMGWtzWDKRBuMRXAhOwhLPdiP0eDNUIaxI6n86rNp0uNctnTqTOOo2t9JQho6fB3sDoPz2RZpuWTIi/4FWuz7@nOT/DvW0ewhDTaB8/Nw/LrAXhgYvsh2@XHJgXvor4KnAt9iMPzEQw3b5VvJvXHUAjOvx8C@/U0cVyqX2X4tdFsXkNSFUB5ffrL29OTb9oPQwjZVhrw60Z0R5ELYSjKv48Jdhmwyx8xPGYHrhOA9bW47WF3RF0Rk39PsIEzvMZyfvLHbQipjut1osbLmmXZfEmShxe57uZFvD3D1rkxVJX0e1EHQocfwnab3srwQZvwY3VZGWXckEZYCm7wPc6lQ1Q3cDIwjbyULr0EbbDLt0wVI4SLNrMcfctQ7zE1r04fKnCWKxPfjSF6J0zNeBPAzUNB7X72sESDbTd2WS7Fu9JeX1LHw1D79ZsGG7s51hUPmMzv8EY8pceiacUutPghobnxFf49GOIn8SXl181R6GYjV7/D26gBMwlIS9eXe@73rPVXPwNfA5fNXvBiI1e5G2x8jq4pTqGmy0hTM76lHpbwvWHtsEV9mjXKLh4889Oya5MtGqOV5SyJnJBV7Tie55IWbw2AiLEfBCW8B6HtbeSz7NuNU17g8i4KSyP@8XevbJONaZ6R0M8gbR1H2NiFKnYSXz3jdEvqB0niYJsNcYAzDXh@rr44INmVn7sT3h0DC3j76mynbG2UTWa4OcGYtsIF3zdMjYAHJ6esCufceDHlgisJL1bNNwXHqggjcuV7@QQy6FM/cilrnczLeeAkRbAoT2MUfIMcEY@il2flxacC8usgji9YVYOc/OPvvKEDk4AMuIbxnDzrMK5QJGCRJuuiuDyZnyO5oWlcgsgoZHAOBUjkGtRO@XOFuBOHdZpSjajzPguS4b2WFwenRD0kEvbHse1i@SO5evDmz@96xsD@SkIdMj4dKz0mN/EH9amZiQ0yB7FmFGrD1WkDppezEhGrU7HcFvZiWetxYVTc4IiMY6aued8kZG1cZnf0ivVNWHMsQt@H/VEo47IcbhWGmvdT7aoMqWIIFZt6mpM2vkSgIBIY8cYvwbY89gBwSXVKvpAJ2orqErNtwB0XSIBtp9BeJuirNZH@kg4LlklcNrVmy2bbqZ7bnS4bpdSLsTHZ@9C/GujZXCr9/vQHozkFscUpgD/R8eQc/vLytqp1jS9fMuca6ruZZLFiT9wTSfX25Ojk8PTs4OztKYhxppQCPCk77qx77JRvE8CWi2x@Mkv54YsH1vxhLw9wMcNd5Us5tiO0OnYG5scZKKyUjhq3Rll26nVFWXkPcjiFKARGi/1o1k8W5pzFZbd0rkU4pBNewkNdv7DDbFGN4xZGeIoCUAQWrywBy1ATBJWukYMgA6v3PFDj8DqnvJblBfiiChcrpOpoi11AsSwgbGavd81Ay1eQdLgf@eIqg2OYs02N5z7V//nXv/Fmcz@H8X@W4xGM/5uPP@gopfXuJOdxIRoUy7ujE5KBa@EbD53pyp54oQ72HRWU@CFI8JIJBME5s8v9LvHIvXcgT1ACCBPNFC2T0aPpQJ7kebKn6@iMx3Ew0lhZRqegBzBsDSoR/XOBvX84TPp2e3vLhKyfqpdzhKylNMYagSNUlD0iEuHST@yPQ5d0Oh0iZpBkUnvb4oLUq86HlvhxwWgVYAXut3sE1sCS5QqY65bL5KpTNxVcSmybSKZEBha4ZK4XONUyGwCIgo@jUh4iuI24FBV2p@g0J2DN6fU8HkEwgHI9RDmxN0BzRCog4rgVUVizXeAXZlgh4N@JldqqGsRfEYyVDXviJtMhYCH/s8FyIhj/Fx/3@ob6dbDp7cXCdg7WX1LI918x4F7I/mkUY234CnglclNvtnRzW1k5J2KJCrjFU/EFUMI5gHPlUv9TnGQHLw6Pfjw@OV1rsjNI6T6YRKRup95XtUZvsBhI92x@LtLnr/TT189fzQW5ylU5dZ@rTcjvM/YAsV950bVOik2sETKN34t4mQ1u3MgyV1wBfMHTxDWqsnI76w063X5UWSP/ZdMbsIpWw5deMOpn7P2XRDY4mEVZeRZfgHl8o7Wv5gjh36w2@f1yNXbQm13do5c6tnwFTZ/PQDCXO3e4VfhrCC6DOXnwE@WTqikC3SUtV1jL@VcZmZeEC3qrK9e3Ow8zcE7LFggcfXyTjD1iiMU@cLL/E40iek1k8GKhA87BKSAVT5XG/F8ZGouXTyva/Leyo3L/bB9Kt0EMHqyqWyzqWzM4xh/7pJ/3R/0Iz7J1rf9J13TrVq4G9rUO7lfpytWJbdZbtXq9GtXkaoQO6MkTTBZmVfBv55qoiVMAUquBYkFUBX9oVyOr6nTkqmc3a2wF3EIcvoUFXzNdu606M736BNxJA56kFL02lauZgpmhoWnmDPj7FPtRVW@ETnIri0Sc4js8JF/163XkQaueIwNf9f5pnRlX/1Rn6YlVhjV9HFrM@0t3bfS33yrmNiGiPGu2Hu8rgLyl67XL/ktL6jmjpvbZHZxcnJz8RaooorklWtGWUNFrxpenuv4RnDwhPWnQeyx3nz6tNaztnVpj35LMxr75yHj0yDQVudlUTh/JJjmRpHZLOv0gfRYq3Ueg1db24/1HH4UK/nzswKAzqHd6WlcddHtC5Vao3Mxwyp523tTx03vZrfMPIT/DtaMOesnJz4cHp4eNZketNF8eN5qnb59XTLhpL@5wqgV3bw4PXh6/PWs0@ZI/H707fHvy6uCF7/tJ5nmZF08G3bqmqkTVSHfQ2zrePt4XKtMf6t26nec5eX9eA2N82Z2@1dUO0P9ZqLxBeFXtK1p38EWo9Co9kOKsaQTGpTE1L8yL1/Hx8vf4GCb8qfEpTo2JMTE90zSnBn1rXE@NayOMj00Pvin8GCEMfWM0NcZGZESmeQfPw7/hcfz6OAZUMSzLp0aOWI0RfI@Pj18DshEQ/gQ/vmEYwJ9xOQVOA5N9PpwbhoJJ4bRTre/X1X342N16p/x6VvGYeDTYqNAj4qC9nTS3P/ewyCTt3UGPTv18IJKG1O9h0K/ouiDJspz0JcuxHYsVSFVsivbMQb166@wVMzztNbOmsIPaNiyrdlCOt2BcDncsi2aOayF@S@I2LMv00glk0exPm6OmqGAOtgunxWwpqmzg3Zbywex05O220u1uN5U4FaWpGKfS7Yz/yLezjsw@Cv4oCj4sr12lfyt3AEYmcMce8BUAB7ks1JFEqswq6IYistVWIBWhyta2vFPfLX/sxwpgFqWWgj/iF9029eaWPZV04fz85cHZwfm5bVaQJZBSRbPeiGZTlFD4FtZDcUC1AIJ/vbUriPBBWdpDOgZyCJ9lFD7hiUMLSq@K4oouPi@gCv/0yUkgwuiWhs612dzdae/stpo7jZ3dna22ud1uN8xmw3y683TXaJiGuWNu77R3zcbO1m5ra2trF2bbu0/1mlDx6AjLtYRk4LfjkZRIqvlMbO1AXdN6KgoV8O3YSu/gS4dYm3QFfGFEZKLoNWCzpt@icciJYs30GgGzAZyd7i1uYSZ42Nra2sWtwWGfdbowqEqIQMJHaiveiivVahX8wpuu2BKPNcHGf7rCBSgSJhTAU8m@xG3za/SjVdlLpNaW1LcrvCiVzadKpdt8qkFRVhnwh/IWPBtUmGU1zQqZ@v@qX2eKisp2/uSNx37zTx@/QKSXpGabEHMbtfNV7fDfDlw@nH84/0sTVLW7u/2brn8rDYDZRTwcUQgVRbgpIB6k/msH665oERRh8LqA@LvQG0HFBf4QNXfnGVfm6iP2H2bwTEC@UEkyDuA0uw1WDJIaO9kDhdyyStMfERlnIQU1ecXLa/u8SCNiWAIHwqa5tRgCFbQzYiMAPsT4J/u2aRG/g8jgG8JmSQE/8xV1G4cBjWTGhT9QrAXMgpMurF7hZWV9vc7BZ5wtvh839Pi2@dziFtgLsVHlyuVq5R4AFPkAI/UNqdzm79kGJHfyAkOD/OFt3FsPGYIy3xNjYTlZPl@qYibU8kZoCbjtWmIJP8mucouZi/U1fPLE/ZD0woGlhHaO3/V6aM2EC9nnILXcDm3VtBJg1sp79bo/sEPlJzlhzIe2AcBAGzFnyu1C05FdqitTGje9SP0aDRqvelHdHDSKRu29fdNwbKMxhT8QWyNofAbhzUUp5/ZNPbKcDvxhEnVHEomd1R3rziNcciEH9k3PGdiGYgWwsF5/BZsBPrNeUK8PFCAewOT6Qit48sSpB92pFaiqglAfWs9e9XIYDOo23u/JTmf67KZXwPo9Gb5tIBMowDysu6sDwAf8WSBjrr4l65zHKbI3BfZC2669f1Z7X7MfP77pTdVw0ODi3zOWikfmp8j8qo3ItferhsVEwhpXsviDv/eDVsuI2ADrAyE3kpWVnMPae5hJlqdh9n8)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006587 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1495 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **60** in Moorhens 2.0 **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- This has been tested to working Incident by ais523 on the official interpreter
- Deadfish~ was tested to output 48 on my own computer, locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 was tested to output 60 on my own computer using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).

### Moorhens

Moorhens is a bit of strange language I designed a while back.  It splits the program up into tokens.  Each token consists of an english word surrounded by whitespace.  Each token performs one of 11 actions based on its MD5 hash. [This TIO program](https://tio.run/#python2#TY9NC4JAEIbv@yuWjcAlEzzUIfDWpaASryJhOrkL7q7sh9Svt1WUPMzMw8y88zFs8E0pzUDiSglRytogxEWntMXmaxZkpWEtfyG0NCU5SZ1hJCSp6ry/yEqDAGk9n@HPmWrbMeW6llelBc9XJybFe4YMetBmrNzVfhr2cJYUy6qndAInmEsbjDZfEon6EPgDo1I3fR4XNGLwqXkDxgY0jI90G8cUoU6PGmN1sJpG8Q6TEyY@LO/kq3JBh2GYhD8) will tell you what command a word evaluates to if you need a quick check (although it won't tell you if that word's actually in Moorhen's dictionary).

Naturally Moorhens found very few tokens in the code to begin with.  A troublesome `or` token was in the python code, but it was removed by deleting the space before it.  Other than that Moorhens plays pretty nice with other languages.  The current Moorhens code contains 30 `xi`s each incrementing the counter and an `ax` to play the program in reverse.  I had to add a little bit of new code over near the Brain-Flak to prevent it from executing the other tokens hanging around in the code.

Comment: I can confirm this works in Incident. (You didn't specify how you'd tested that.)

Answer (score 10):

## 63. [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 1605 bytes

````
#16  "(}+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.qc]PkPPX'#)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   ␉['][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>.}+?
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.---.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.

#
'(((p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or'{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts(p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<q>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-^_^_X2229996
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .006414 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1681 bytes)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkmfjF/pSBtkGQBIvUpIlgaQt29Ksu@2W1pIfYZKWS2CRhIWXAVCkLNOx193Yw9znssf5j7nuV8yP9GZWgSQoUnZ3xG7EQhJQQGVlZuWrKrP0ewkvchL510M/ykjG0oz0E@@KJQZ5ck0eUy/drjckiUMlUX/seuGQZCNGvDAeZ2Tg@SyVXJqRNolzLAY2SIkkjPYFmDSIEoJDSHDpE4@4cUwufDoyXOJ7HDaNAuzPWBInDO4pCRnrkzRmrjfwXE6HsGnGwtSLwtQgnntJJp7vkz7zYcCSuFsDZGScFj4JUobUjyQClxvfYnXxVmYAE7L5dFlMEz7diMR87vNZTxIax8CkVCKnwHjmBSwlXqakhNHUQxnCkJSFfS6peCHdiNCwOEty5VFCgd9xwnGnLMlgegbHS0YsYYCSIvFhQgOiThIvAxGgIA/ICaMJOUsY04AKKIClLo2BjxWSQCxCChlOxOCKajaVw@MjBRQmRhg0zqRS0jj7118kSowWKZ878NeSZUc6/O0ZuSl3sQ1cADJQapyoVCOtbyQ1u10Gf1P7whwmMwmwSiAVn5hRnJmAmSYZsLds6Vd1I/YLZEnzliYKRiSg@qAL8jwkb2p8Xu44SRhwsRQpvYQp@1E4BGnCVJNxiNIIyY4FCnCjsJ/WCLsCmUWh0FA04fI9G3mgshQVQi9APNRFyQsH4OIEFwDLy@U5p5tG/pjDwcg0Q/MDmcBQxPh8QN6QAfV8HAL9iEpwnbB07Gc4Zhz2Ue@BF7K@QeZsuFEfgYLoCshRQMo/gM8EBU/jTAEwqCHiU8Wuf/71b/3hEPAcuG6U9HNjfUP6kTsOgGHKmaVgiGiuUUh9zhbA1ZC6GA4Erqjv9WmG5MPrnARnglOdRGO/TyIgmEw8cKwRvQJnHAyYmzFh4tE4Ax5rJKCXIj54wm5h4gG9AMVyApw2n7ZOHj8FLblMGIwejLPBLtHjQ6Kk5gf10b766H6XAW@aoVXKpjl0wNqMCv8Eb8r3DOfNwVKfaD1nXoRe5MejMcQM6AnTGKJJgsJ0KUwnxaCSQcyrkQsuaB6JwNC5i06YkjByAX49nxi3EWEDOF5Hv80xLHU6h1s1MdYvWBhYJxhZlq4FCT@aAGHOGwZOsOkQidMhBVJZPqEDMSFBkX9ZndplCJaO2C4Y2dUvPNAO2gGEmlwZhTkCeKMuYACb0F7BKQJ6DVhcEaKXmiTeAJQcgN0m18Rl6AzgFUzEOSQy5oaRemBH0YBYen17@wfKzxLzQH9vUv2L@V0d4@RvqfmADNiE@DQcjukQDDkKYQh1XRZnuQfBTNIMfOR2GOQf9TymG@lIKj@@TZvHtjzaF2hg9BHayyM0RbMHQQUgat0HLyc0GXJPJH0vAX/xr29TB4CrW8TljwiywsBH@Q4W5gsTGBmbMnecgbuBIU9GnjsC20XuQuGwIjreJg@fitQh5OiDBWlkxm4/qEuGufiEbNyJQkeNruOBqI@o2isfuPKLH76PmabBBsTRgkWIUIWvhkkNsL1caLCan@JOAsLffOnmnrXYXizkCQL@BRemhH0eg8LAnr1hiCA0XCz7hcjopaECS4WXeiB1XMDR1s@eH@N68JaJPQzIXaxlxWAewY4GhucLNHbMlSAxdxQRPSRKzoMq8/X0E7BlponLG3phEyFrBshJRXnxrjmiT2JfdntBJe11OE5SqZGOLPdqsIb5KZhQOPZ9eBmH3MVUpt2ArbksTQ1wGJCtgbsR4E6uMm22CpiNkmhC2ExzlE3k/qRCno4vvOn/Q424yJe4w6wKauCf/oge1gDnipDlXHRrEEJ4Z8DeC9j0kBcerkUD2CItt858tz3FTWJXkuPrbBSFjdVoIi976mK39sYMYHEx4uvN66hcRMUHvPTCywi1ZAbz1rll2NsrKGC3vz5y4KUjflsBXWNrvYePToOLAb9tAAjRCm4ZG@8IojASxEFCXkjNV/xhQMTcxMFqYFoh/4SBnQ@ZvtcwL7zQvGCDuyCPnjx5zmEGFxfeXUAgBsxn5s8NYMn4YpOUYD8yWlu4yIqcz8ZJ5ut9M8Mn@@9/64O817Uxotcp7GAvF43zkE1QM/rgTuXkQ/GF3zYr8tPYh@zmBzhcirtW6i8am3Htk1cMrB32FyFPaoBT3wcfApGBb6@bM3iCP@6z@XMzUi7D1fVPjA69QAdb3jEsrkB4xTUdd1Z3Ybm1iAs0uNlP/Ij2TZF@eWypUSF7NqXDKLw2C9HcSC7@AKvzdZYs861sNM7G4o5J1o9058X49z0XzCGt7YMn9mH@uAMemNi5y3aF2yQQXfQjn16aF9g8H0Bz81TFZBJvCBnd/HkX2NvTmLrMnKT42Gg2L2F35EOefPrb69OT79oPRwjbpsQX943onocurCdh9mNMMEuf3/6M4XE7cKkP1tcQtodlDr0gJu@WYH16cY15@ejP2xBSHVarRI@WyceyihLHdw9y3c2DRJ2Fj3MjSA/Zj1YdWDq8AKZb7xead9qEF@nLFCcVhjTAnG5D7KFXlOiuT1MwjSyXLrsCbfDb90wVVwgXbWbZ@p6h3mJqnmbelaksR8aeG8HqHXM144sPL3ctare3AUs0WD/jt@VQfMvt9RmjfVxqv33XYCM3wwThDpP5A9FI7M0x@ynYhRHdJTQ3muDfnUv8KLpi4r55Ffqykas/EG10n5sE7C/Xh/fdH1nrWy@FWAO3zVHwciNXmetv/I6hKUogOUtJ3bC@q56NxnxqPDdeGMfGKTn1/Cj9rjwgNU1Tcd9sykvQi8Sjoe6iDRfbG4fxnegrXnBbZMBpLa8TwjcvyetC6aL0WoIAmjCeD893@KSEWfo4AEfLosQgHE5VabWqaZIYhCobhgA2h@LlL6xAiMpaSsB3Mg7rDUinQ8o3031r356RFpH3ZdLrCaw8Fz6cxrxu9UoM7ZRpr1VW3r1Tyko33CeWwkEZpECbQekK3MDjD8HncuokpAEvemB7PlNHVFbAsLGcNqJhHzYUr0OPJy9ulIj6gChC8c3bP/7ez6uMQwaTDLyU@iAIrItHARtFk0eCbk79II4pVikRByxhvkhv9KcHJJ14mTsSxUXwu9dHZ7t5ZSiv0cPLCe4kClwIpULXAHigmVCa4KYfMWGuOeHFqPmkIJiNg5BMvH42Sg2w0NBlvPI0r4YAJwmChVkSobnXyHPSZ7i28uzs0xh060fRJU8KkZN//F3Uw6DTQxPC9pw8L9AWKBIwZpsXoVw3GgPXcyRfWBLlICoKGULyGCRyDc7GxHeNuCPKC3Vgifq8TIVkRKnq6cEp0Q@JgscLWLVyvIFaPnj1lzcdq9f6RgIT9tkmJspcbvLP@kM7lWtkDuLM0K6K3RZ0L3sVIpencj4tLGXzyu3CqIQ3ERXbXF3zslPAq@Dc7tiEl514bTHEFQfLy5AFpxm8ahy1cJpWWYUNegAJr36akW08g2EgEmiJujnBUw0soeCQ8pR8JSO0Fd0l9rYFb0IgPlbtgtYyLSpmouYzdjHm@7erulFvtPh0yuetZpu3EtaPsK7b@dCd9Mx0LpVud/qzVZ@C2KIEwB@Y6DmHvz27KRtt6@vXlF5DejxTHJ4ro3uXb06enxyenh2cvT4FMc7ELEtHURLQZYhAI4h92CeOIp8XykEeicfSH4eNRejIBSe/eyeXRTuPASQPVOSE6ypXi5IWg1Rtrj6cOnjUGKLinDSo/WZDsOHMyKQF7LwDdlaZWbzlSFSVlClpEtsimrbay@GFuB7BRUBkBfbnFw95S6jNQDhXAZzzLWAEkxsnMftf4vzk4PT0x5wj1I84B2DpR9QLhI8Onr9YJ1ygiQBr/fnCAI/lieLhFLaBEL8G3DKxbj23mCg/d5g7NMTrkSiGUX8ZktJFXQttaIAB1QefRGPmGVCKTknQ/w1y4KcQAPt98OiL6wwDAkRCUcpa1LPkEkzdWKxPNSJLCJu21uvP4PAT2PW7H8XgMofjmNNNRzhdZv7zr38TxzbdDNr/nrcH0P5P0f5gooDW6/yCx4VoUCxvnp@QFFYZMfGATgtzwkCPC4kXjhnxApDgFRcIggtml/Nd4lE7b0CeoAQQJkYsDFKcHkt66ijL4n3TxHV5GPkDg9dF2BT0ADHOcKPA/DzGUzSIq@bO9s6WDWk306/mCHlxdohJukCoaftgP9KVF7c@Xrik2WwSOYUsj7V2HCFIs0w/NOSPC0bLACuJJbxDYAwMWY6AvnY@TC3Tqq3hUPQ/xVZIz4HVWegFArzKGwCi4ecwl4cMK0iUiwrrvGya8WB4Pd@awL4gjEiAcuJnqXNEOiASuDVZWrNd4Bd6eCburewJjaIa5LcIxvP2fXmT6RCwkP/aYDkhtP9DtDtdS//W23QOuLCdg/XjPvX2YR3OhTw@DSMszhwBr0Stm/WGae9oBT@Rc1TALXrFV0AJfgB@5TLvUxSnB08Pn/9yfHK6dlzFIZXbYApR2s1qVzdqnd6iodyy@blInxyZpy@fHM0FWeQq77rN1Sbktxm7g9hbUfVYJ8U71gjZ1h9FvEzHNk5kmawVAJ@KPG2NqqrdzDq9ZrsbltbIf910llwyKnh8DK1uyk@SFbIhwCzqOmfRJZjHdw7J9AwhvC/F4zIvH41nUfW22WdXJh6eSIY574G1UW2ucKuJAz0hgzl5iBP5l7ItA90lLVdaS7qLjMxrMgt6xZHr050vM@CneQ0SXB//JwNPW2Bb5gEnj39lYciuiQpRLKAQHOgYcuFEq83/Kai2OMYtaPNf8pLmbd8@VG78CCJY2XT4BtCZgRt/7JJu1h10Q/Rl59r8yTRM50Yt@61rE8Kv1lbLo5ZdbVSq1XJYUcshBqAHD3DfOCtDfDs3ZEOeApBe9jUHVlWIh61y6JRpUy33W/UKHwGvkEvewIBvqWnclOnMLD@AcFKDLwnDqM3Ucqrh/tAyDHsG/H2KvLBs1gIa36gykad4Go7ky161ijwY5XNk4JvZPa1y4@qemnyn6uTLmjkMHB79lVUb/f33kr1DiKzOqo/qjfuPNV2VTbPSfXblKB06qBuf3d7J5cnJO6WkyfaW7IRbUsmsWF8fmubHjx8hzhNyr6P0OvfV9sOHlZqzs1upPXYUu/bYtu7ZtqbW69rpvXuqTU4UZbuhnH5QPkul9j1QbGPn/uN7H6WSVDpvV@Ey2gZwIZU@NuFjs1dtdoy23mt3pNKNVPoyQ8DWtPkKQaudZ3wIXNt7L@De1Hud@OTF4cHpYa3e1Ev1Z8e1@unrJyUbXrYXb9jVgLdXhwfPjl@f1epiyF@evzl8fXJ08NTzvDjt99N@NOq1q4au60a7BwxMf662q60sy8j784qxdbxz/FgqPWtPX5t6E6i/kEqvOLTe1WDAV6nUKXXUR/VHdcu3rqypfWlfvoyOl7/Hx9DhTa1PUWKNrJHdt217arHX1vXUuraC6Njuw5PBjxVA07MGU2tohVZo2yt47v4NjqOXxxGgimBYNrUyxGoN4Dk8Pn4JyAZA@BP8eJZlAX9T6wp@Ld/m14dzy9Ik2E73tnfi@s7nDhZNyPZer8OmXtaTSU3pdnBxL5lpt2sK05LrYB/YP5udnz87ODs4PzdRaaXStFmuPq7qj@FqtavN/PGo1OcyNiAWSIqqqnFXcWiLOjyxLuMRRsfuVcs3dH88w9BQsSsa9@pty3EqB3l7C9p5c9dxWEpdzoSjCK5UlV1RX5Xt7rQ@qMsabtj2wLXsBti6hW9b2ge72VR3trV2e6euRYmsTOUoUW5m4ke9mTVVfmn4o2n4Mb@3tRu1CSAAo/FXAQ9Qk7dv3@Lf28nVRLR4Q3x7u@gsvuAFu2UyokQpzUoY6EKyta3BZodpWzvqbnUv/2nd14AdWWlo@CMr0lzgLbuE3Eslw3kl23XoAfE7mHBHPjN82FI09iQZLql1wYZeKDXb4FxpyuAKTigbMzYZjydscT310n366RONYdUyHQMDdr2@t7u9u9eo79Z293a3tu2d7e2aXa/ZD3cf7lk127J37Z3d7T27tru119ja2tqD3u29h2ZFKvXZAKsBMUlhLYgGSqzo9iO5sQvpbeMhsA3rBZ6PNfEkMTJGbQlPgYlKtBu0QDXWnBmgERWIHVsqzaQ@Vqm39hyMErNmWyorOERpSCW9EW1FpXK5DNHkc1tuyMdGKrVY2EcBlGQcXEq/Rtv2t/AXp7QfK40tpdFtlQR21X6oldr1hwbk96We@KhuwbdeiRtb3S6Rqfd/9QsZxWBSMJhVI9rQWF4La1qzrUJrw/vkKoCgnKbp7k/94dCr//TxK2xPiKLUtwmxd1D/3/Sm@G3C7cP5h/N3dTCGvb2d3wHwO5sX6F2s4gMGC9w42LSMHyTeS4rZYrhYyqHxcgy7hoVlEDQN37tA21j5Jsyl@In/hyl8k5AvNAoVGxBW3BpPYUmFh5ieRm7mhQ8VezH31hapesKycRISyxElFUThOYsmUEFLJi0E4Pk1hBbVa9kO8ZqIDJ6w2OcU8JqPqLaw6bNQ5Vx4Pc2RijUIzkkbRhd4KYyvVgX4TLAl5uMGfTFt0bd4BfYCrLS6aj5auwXQsXoAo3QtJZ/mH5kGbEnVBYYa@dPTuDUe9jXafE6chWVn/n2piplUyWqBI@G0K7Ej/aq62g3ut5xvwYMH7oe4E/QcLWhl@KxWA2cmXaqeAKlkraCl204MzDpZp1r1eq1A@1WNOfNBywJgoI2YU@1moemwlasr1WpfOqH@LezVjjph1e7VxrXK@9aXGm1ZtSn8gdhqfu0zCG8uSjVrfamGDm3CH279ViQRt9IqdVZLQzDkUvVbXzq017I0x4eB1eoRTAb4TDt@tdrTgLgPnesDHf/BA1r121PH13UNoT40Hh11Mmj0qi1831dpc/roS2cM4/dVeLaAjK8B8zBuVQeAD/hzQMZCfUvWBY9TZG8K7AWtVuX9o8r7Suv@/S@dqR70akL8@9ZS8cj8FJkv2ohaeV80LC4SXnlV5Z@9/Z@NSkrkGlgfCLkWF0YKDivvoSdeesPsfwA)

### Rundown

This program prints **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ was can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).

### Brian & Chuck

Brian and Chuck are two mutually modifying, BrainF**k-like languages. Like SMBF the memory tape starts containing the polyglot. Brian’s memory pointer is Chuck’s Instruction pointer and vise versa. The polyglot is split with a triple backtick, such that the part of the polyglot prior to ```` ``` ```` is put on Brian’s memory tape, while Chuck gets the portion after.

Backtick is used as a string declaration for Pyth which is used to hide most of the polyglot from its parser. The first instance of such a backtick string is on line 2, and we’ve added a an empty string just prior to this to create Brian & Chuck’s delimiter here: ```` #/*0|7//```" ````

The `+-<>` commands for both Brian & Chuck function as you’d expect based on BrainF**k. The `,` and `.` commands also function as you’d expect with the caveat that only Brian uses `,` and only Chuck uses `.`.

For the more unique commands, we have the `?`, which is a no-op if the current memory cell is zero, otherwise it switches control between Brian and Chuck. Also, curly braces will repeatedly move the tape head to the right (`}`) or left (`{`) until the cell under the memory pointer is zero/null. And finally, all instances of `_` are replaced with null bytes, which makes for a convenient landing space when using curly braces to advance the memory tape.

The program starts by reading line 1 with Brian. The first operation encountered is `}` in the Hexagony capsule, and it’s here where we begin making changes. The `}` advances Chuck’s pointer to the `_` I added to line 6. I chose line 6 because, as an even numbered line, it’s subject to Retina’s friendlier parser, which is needed for consecutive `+`’s. Second, this line leaves a buffer line between itself and Labyrinth’s code on line 4, which is needed to maintain the labyrinth walls. And third, we don’t need any spaces, and this is the final line of Whitespace’s command to end the program. This line is also located just prior to the SMBF/BF/Minimal-2D code space, and it aesthetically pleases me to keep the BrainF**k derivatives together.

With Chuck pointing at the `_`, Brian advances its IP to `+` which I’ve inserted in the Hexagony Capsule along with a `?`. The `+` gives the null valued `_` a positive value which is needed the `?` to transfer control to Chuck where we read the bulk of this answer.

So when we switch control, Chuck is pointing at the `_` in `#_>++++.>.}+?`. Chuck then advances it’s IP to the `>` which moves Brian’s pointer to the `2` in line 1. From here, we increment the `2` up to `6` with `++++`, and then output the 6 with `.`. Then we advance Brian’s pointer again with `>` landing on the `3` in line 1, which we output with `.`.  Finally, we advance Brian’s pointer to the end of its code segment with `}`, increment the null memory position with `+`, and transfer control back to Brian with `?`. And from here, we let Brian advance to the end of his tape, ending the program.

It’s super easy to get lose track of who has control and where the pointers are at, so I want to share [this](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#tVRbc6JIFH5O/4V56dBuNahANzchIDEzZrd2a6awkslmapEoEVQSA0RQySTOX882ms1kamcf95y2@9w5dfqznxFCcLDMotUkSWewnMcwSfNVCafJIi7AJCyhC/Ns8TBbZKVUCxDBZRxG@zAAwHJ1/QDlLC/l62USpuJkvprcvpWl5TUU@z8WAc/PiBoQcvy2dayohz1B5DlZbg77axv74VSR7ifB4HYw@IKRwFGNs1MNILlJnjqyPB6PuTGE8MDHgX/Iu51Os20bZrPdszFt9yg5oFTgFUU4PzjgKRxgrKv4/ArfA@QeAARV47B3MAYIoJHbYiS5EusCoLHDjE7QcnzJFQPXB@gRoK/bOrBbOWd1aMvv71IY6dZHtjti4OeDj6cn56dtxRGR0vfayvnFe0SZor9qtUtl2tnpSd@7@NxW9im//f7n6cXg15MPSZLkRRQVUTYP3JYkiqLkBqyB6peW2@qWZQn/GjUlzTO8HkB9t7qQRYd9/SNAZ7tocSiwhCeAfOTzx8qxQhZkTSp6S28/Zd735XnMkVTkJluSOZnTiFJakfiCPFTkgdxlHo3YGTMmd0xMyLQiM5KSlNIf6vz3uvOyT17GSmUsraxIWVclU3bOPO8TKzZlH75hnBBCWH9kXbFOF3RHVyNCBOBDLtCNXDHufQaxAupW4MdVUgYcbOOhj2FgI7kYDmU7XyZpySkMHrV/ux2N@iefT0Yjub4zhCqn0eq1xB6jrttyXo5jFO1GLAEWhXmez4fYDruhPQmLGDbC5Wzt06DVeAyPVlsGc9ikTSGezDOoE9tunrzIGpNfRNO24yKc7Jqw8b4rno/X4YLn6LBSpgonhGkErWwJqcqgTmpNE66o4/CGLriuoQjZksMVly3x43bP/OPW4Xck1CwItfFld4VH3mEhLEbYqft4FrW5vLysf5eb9WYv7YS97fLV@VapCS4SOA8hRlvE1/1DTRf464dY0AzebFkv3D0UWDscVoWaOQz@GXiXorp7gCT7jKMK87Dx25MsLbJFLC2yGVQtwDEC3et4lqTAcdl/qyhiRneDMF7F8Wa12sSv9CEpjsKbmzBvyrJsS2ygUFEsUzctVTHbpmVqOjV0vU2VNu2YHYu0KaEmNUzdom1Ts1RN0yzm1a2O3AQoiqdJGsMcFsnXOJviHIv0mFNN7ohTO6ztJJ0sVlHsFGWUZNLcBXchmwEPhccagXwu2FtWZnex0KAAbUGUFDnULLt@JLaOCxq4TsEqQKKaaRlqNBrsMbl3OZXzpAJ04zSqB4C4OhkVT5lOv6V/2Ogox6qG1WEX7avztCMgV@lIRfiAgr2R15gtQDuwKRTBKvm/VljB6eYNYH4E0U@E7/SKpn9h6430E32zvmNvclEU5rtoNkuUd@OnhixDjBUdQmrU9/9NdPbLYdvV6Gr0RWFgsCzj@W8) configuration which runs Brian & Chuck with a switch for stepping through the code for debugging purposes. I’m sharing the verbose version of this debug switch which also has a `@` command that only applies in debug and will terminate the program. The current solution skips over the `@` in line 1, so it’s not an issue, but it is something to be aware of if this gets reworked in the future.

### S.I.L.O.S.

@RohanJhunjhunwala updated Tio’s S.I.L.O.S. interpreter such that  `1=61 //` threw an error, which invalidated our test case in the Test Driver. C'est la vie.

This left me with a quandary - do I update the code or the test? @RohanJhunjhunwala rightly pointed out that the `=` could be replaced with a `+` to address the issue, so changing the code sounded like the ideal solution, assuming it was compatible with an old enough version of the interpreter. But I ended up taking a different path that came about while I was working on adding a different language: J.

Today, I’ve kind of given up on J at this point. I think it might be possible to add if I’m willing to heavily rework the top 2 lines (and to be honest, I’m increasingly disinclined to do so). But at the time, I had come to the conclusion that J had a blocking issue with Thutu’s requirement of having a trailing `//` on each line that didn’t start with a `#`.

I posted to the Polyglot Development board to see if anyone had an idea to get around Thutu’s requirement and @ais523 suggested injecting Perl in Thutu’s parser so it could get past the regex syntax requirement.

Cool!

I later realized that this Thutu hack would allow S.I.L.O.S. to use a more conventional solution, which would allow the S.I.L.O.S. test to remain valid, and golf down both the S.I.L.O.S. and Thutu code. So I jumped in with both feet and gave Thutu its Perl injection and changed the S.I.L.O.S. code to `print 61`.

### Thutu

The Thutu hack is based on the `\` command. Here's the documentation's definition:

> (When the next character is punctuation) Remove any special meaning the next character might have, even if it's a slash or backslash. Removing the special meaning of a slash prevents it delimiting the end of a regexp, making it possible to write slashes within a regexp.

And this is the code snipped that @ais523 suggested (after I golfed it down and added the necessary bits to include it in the polyglot):

```
/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
```

So how does the injection work? Well, a quick look at the [interpreter](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/thutu/impl/thutu.pl) showed this line of code:

```
@regexps = split /(?<!\\)\//, $_, -1; # Split on / not preceded by \
```

Now, I’m not the Perl-y-est guy around, but fortunately the comments tell the story. This bit (`\\/`) from the Thutu line of the polyglot is being parsed by Thutu’s intrepeter  as escaping out both the second `\` and the `/`, where traditionally, we’d expect only the second `\` to be escaped out.

And because we’ve formatted the line to otherwise look like a valid regex, we get past the syntax checks and arrive at this piece of the interpreter where I believe our Perl injection (`;print"24";exit}}__DATA__`) gets executed:

```
foreach $regexp (@regexps)
{
$regexp and print "/$regexp/ $regsep "; # Guards are just Perl regexps.
}
```

Originally, this was intended to just allow Thutu to bypass its regex syntactical requirements on a line, but what actually happened is it little broader. Every line after the injection point stopped requiring any regex syntax. Why is that? Well, we kinda crashed the compiler. But it still produced a good result.

This raised a philosophical dilemma though, did the program run without error? It wasn’t entirely clear. so @ais523 created a [metapost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/if-code-fails-to-compile-but-runs-anyway-does-that-count-as-executing-without/12503#12503) to answer this question. The answer came back with an unequivocal yes – the *program* ran without error.

Cool. So now, Thutu runs through this line:

```
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
```

And everything past this compiler crash point doesn’t need to conform to Thutu syntax. This means that the space between `=begin` and `=end` now has virtually no syntax requirement as long as you don’t cut in the middle of any existing code pieces.

### Where to go from here

Ok, there is one syntax requirement between the `=begin` and `=end` . Any code pieces that use Brain-flak tokens `(){}[]<>` without being preceded by a `#` will be exposed to Brain-Flak. But there is almost certainly a way to work around this one. So where are the safe spaced to add code in here?

There are a few:

•   Before or after `print 61`

•   Before `=end`

•   After `=begin`

•   After `<>{`

•   After `}<>`

@Luke mentioned in polyglot chat he thought he had an answer to go next, and I'd point to these locations as probably good locations.

Good Luck.

### Incident Report

`#<R>"3"O.s` became `#<q>"3"O.s` because `R`is no longer a token and this detokenizes `q`

`$'main'` became `$'main'3` In order to detokenizes `' ␊` and `'3`

`###;console.log +39` became `###;console.log 39` Because  `3` was no longer a token.

`sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap` became `sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap` Which detokenizes `:` and `sa`

`]>+.-- -. >]` became `]>+.---.>]` because `--.` and `.>` are no longer tokens.

`1k10v` became `1k1x0v`to detokenize `10`

### A Couple things I forgot to mention

I golfed off the `3` at the end of the C/C++ processor directive on line 1. This was to counter the addition of characters to line 1 so I didn't have to totally rework all the 2D languages. Just most of them.

Also, I added a `-` between the `)` and `(` on line 1 because I added a `+` earlier that incremented a memory cell in BF and SMBF which I needed to decrement back to zero.

Answer (score 10):

## 75. C++11, 2040 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1011)(22)S ␉\4n;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d@O6O4111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}() )wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":"75"
#include<stdio.h> 
main (  )  {puts(p);u8;}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72" )';end;
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"# xi xi xi xi \++++>/ xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''         16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004835 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2122 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTvLdttKcmvjF2bTAnkNgCRepKgXSEqyLU10xx4plmzPMUnLLbBJwsLLAChSlumTbXKymP1sspz/mG2@Yn7kpqobfEikbN@TLEKLQANd3fXsqupq@oqmw99@K@CHnEX@7cCPMpKxNCO9xLthiUGe3ZID6qX1ak2SOFQS9UauFw5INmTEC@NRRvqez1LJpRlpkTifxcAGKZCE0Z4Ak/pRQnAICa594hE3jsmVT4eGS3wPYI@tHYBPowBhMpbECYNrSkLGeiSNmev1PZfjImySsTD1ojA1iOdek7Hn@6THfBiwIMCtwGRklC69EugMqRdJBD5u/IDc@VORAUzIZiyzmCac5YjEnP8Z5@OExjEQKRXIORCeeQFLiZcpKWE09VCOMCRlYY9LK55LOCI0XOaS3HiUUKB3lPC5U5ZkwJ7B5yVDljCYkiLyQUIDoo4TLwMRoDAPyRmjCblIGNMACyiBpS6NgY57KAFZhBgyZMTgymo0lKPTYwWUJkYYNM6kQlK7@NdfJUqMJileOvBtyrIjHf35BbkrdrANVMBkoNg4UalGmt9IanY6DL4T@8ocJFMJZpVAKj4xozgzYWaaZEDeoqXfVI3YX0JLGg80sWRIAqoHuiAnIXlb4Xy5oyRhQMVCpPQaWPajcADSBFaTUYjSCMmWBQpwo7CXVgi7AZlFodBQNObyvRh6oLIUFUKvQDzURcmLRcDFCcsALC@X5wxvGvkjDgcj0wzND2QCQ3HGkz55S/rU83EI9ONUguqEpSM/wzGjsId6D7yQ9QwyI8ONeggURDeAjsKk/AWsm2BptXGiABjUEHFWseuff/1bbzCAeQ5dN0p6ubG@Jb3IHQVAMOXEUjBENNcopD4nC@AqiF0MBwQ31Pd6NEP04W2OghPBsY6jkd8jESBMxh4srCG9gcXY7zM3Y8LEo1EGNFZIQK@Fj/CE3QLjAb0CxXIEHDdnWycHz0FLLhMGowejrL9D9PiIKKn5Qd3fU/c3Ogxo0wytVDTNgQPWZpT4K3hSvmc4bw8X@kTrufAiXEV@PByBz4CeMI3BmyQoTJcCOyk6lQz8XoVccUFzTwSGzpfomCkJI1ewrmeMcRsRNoDjdVy3@QwLnc7g7psY6y1ZGFgnGFmWrjgJPxoDYk4bOk@w6RCR0wEFVFnO0KFgSGDkb@6zdh2CpeNsV4zs6FceaAftAFxNrowlHgG8VhUwMJvQ3tKiCOgtzOIKF73QJPH6oOQA7Da5JS7DxQCrggk/h0hG3DBSD@wo6hNLr9brP1B@lpiH@nuT6l/M7@oYmX@g5kPSZ2Pi03AwogMw5CiEIdR1WZzlKwg4STNYIw/dIH@p5z7dSIdS8eAhbu7bcm@/hAO9j9Be7qEpmj0IKgBR6z6sckKTAV@JpOclsF7824fYAeDmAXL5I4LcI@Cj/AgJs8AERsYmzB1lsNzAkMdDzx2C7SJ1oViwwjs@RA@vlrGDy9H7c9RIjN16WpUMc/4KyXh0Ch01ujoPeH2cqnXvBVf@8ovvz0zTYM3E0ZxE8FBLbw2TGmB7udAgmp9jJgHubxa6@cqapxdzeYKAf8XAlLDPI1AY2LM3CBGEhvOwv@QZvTRUIFR4qQdSxwCOtn5xcorx4B0TOQzIXcSyZWceQUYDw/MAjR0zJUjMHUZED4mS06DKPJ5@ArLMNHF5Q19KImTNADmpKC/eNZvok8jNHgZU0lqF4yiVCmnLcrcCMcxPwYTCke/DwyjkS0xl2h3YmsvS1IAFA7I1MBsB6uQy06b3AbNhEo0Jm2qOsg7d71TI89GVN/l/qBEX6RJX4GpJDfzVz@hhBXCmCFnORbcCwWX3PArQz5N3nGOk91kCsaEP8UCKb7MheDrdJTJtRjEDku55EgXohORc1Rye0CmK8SnyQvVO2djYUPaUllKB1j60Gtjax1YZWvu8pfMWwhnY4iMqvIW9bT4C33WVaXs280TromonmLV@8WKVtvf2at0Kbdv5vYp3DYIJxA6A1vEG8yhas4lNTZNbY2DUuOpLgv0LUM5LSPnISw8jcR8SxMXGQZoj60iyEEbtvi@VFz1Vkau@NQMQnxHfrs8i5OWp@IBXXngdoY2awax1aRl2/d4UsN9ZHdn30iG/3ANdIWu1h49Og6s@v6wB2MvTAMgpcI@EcuGuDDORKALLH3OwIAojQQrIywup@ZrfDIge6@i576TvEfOMwZofMH23Zl55oXnF@o9BHj97dsJh@ldX3mNAIBSke3ZfA5aMrtbJDHKz4UoQJ/ekfjFKMl/vmRne2X//Ww@kv6qbIb1NIZu/njcuQWioJ73/qKryofjAL@vV@mnkw07vB3O4FDN46s8b6@faI68Z2D6oNeQbPKDU98GfgMjAz60aN6wLf9Rjs/v6SbkM7@cCYnToBTpY9pZhcQXCI@Y33Ps8MsuDhEZMgxufxI9ozxRbUY8tNCpkzyZ0EIW35lJkM5KrnyB1lnOQxd4zG46ykbjihvNHuvNi/H5vQeaQVv3wmX2U3x6BByK2HrNdsWzQVevHPr02r7B52YfmelYFM4k3gN3t7P4Y2LvzmLrMHKd4e9R/hKM05orkrcfAIHtMfHF9DMQLXYis4aLxGCCw6PPL77E6bgQu9cH0asLwsN6jL8nIeyBVn17dYjwb/n4DQqyDcpno4EOabrls1YgeLTZki8pSHD8@3nXz8bu760eLIhSfwI1g78x@FJQgsngBiKDaW2o@aiRepC/2f6mwLMwH1jkjekMhP/BpCraS5RJnN6Ahfvme7WLIcEc@TRat71nuA6Jme/DHtnGLkbHnRhDchanig@@ttdYQ876HOdJiGiww8stiKD7lbvQFpEEYib9915dGboa7p0fM6Cfck9i44NZwyS6M6DGhudEYv4@u4GF0w8R1fVj6spaqn3A/us9NApLv1eE990fW@s5LwfnAZb1bvF5LVeb6a9/vkVdRlMDONSVVw/quetYa87lxYrw0To1zcu75UfpdecC@PU3Fdb0pL0CvEo@Guos2vNxeP2wtYTzEkUN@fUTB1B9E/tbOwKRwedQKRkkfvX1@/1knN3dStv1DJzVPa6LQzu@Puvhr@PuRgWBVBHy6h/nNvLneWH7g0fLNwONswg4AR65n8djamdtYkrK1xgW4c5jDxB2O6e13TfBH8eQxYefxhG9pXvO69byQlFbycju885K8vJrOTzAKJ6GbMF5Wmm2USQGLXaMAXHIWJQbhcKpKy2VNk8QgXNyDEMBmULyKjIU8UaBOCXjZjMPCZqzdJsW7yZ61Z09Jk8h7Mul2xay8pHQ0iXn597UY2i7SbrOo6LpSVDrhHrEUDsp8kPBaUHoPru/xm6BzwToJacBrh9ieceqIAiW4QKxKD2nYg1z0TejxGoAbJaLMJmq5PO//x997ebF@wIDJwEupD4LA46UoYMNovC/w5tgP45hisR/ngBTIF1UC/fkhScde5g5FjR489Jvji528wJofd8HDGSahS1QIpUIXbG8zmgmlCWp6ERNWlSOej5oxBWFvFIRk7PWyYWqALwtdxgu4s6IiUJIgWJglEVplhZyQHsN8jBc5Po1At34UXfPaClLyj7@LsjJ0emhC2J6h5@ccSxgJuD2b13JdNxoB1bNJvrAkykFUFDIE7xFI5BbWBBPvNeIOKa93gyXqs2ovohEV3@eH50Q/Igqe0mHx1/H6avHw9R/ftq1u8xsJTNiimVhv4nKTf9G37VSukBmIM0W7Wu62oHvRqxC5OJFztvBEiB@AzI1KrCaiYpura1a9DfhhErc7NubVW16iDzE3wVOaMIX1AY8an1osmmZRhb1d4GVEP89IHY8yGYgEWuL4ieDhIFYicUhxQr6SIdqK7hK7bsGTEIiPxe@gudhRL5c0zBfsasRT/5uqUa01OTvFy2ajxVsJ60V4PNL@0Bl3zXQmlU5n8otVnYDYogTAn5q4co7@/OKuaLSsr19TcGqyPFUcXnLC5V28Ozs5Ozq/OLx4cw5inAouC8dREtCFi0AjiH2IOcPI5@dNII/EY@mP3cYT7jekJzmgqpIiJQ1iWwQ81JO5Y8nFKutyUTRFH/ck874Hnbn76Hskd3XkjGs7V6ySLru5yswAUHiwJkfgV2fEg@HcrXFXnB2ZNIEhHRji4HOC50/rGLvfy@GFwPfxGYSes7EMxVldQK0HQl4FcE63gBFErmVi@n9EeQxx5MeUI9SPKAdg6UfYlxAfH568fPP6aBX3EtocZgVkbiFLB/xHE8gSwA/2uYXjMdLMbqL8GHDmGMDvD0VtmvoL15bOy8xoSX10zD6sbVwUfBOe4uIm6EcMcuin4Eh7PfAMV7cZOhbwqKKyPC8vywUQgDGPcxUiSwibNlePg8BxjCGXcz@KwUUOx2dO152odpj5z7/@TZyidjJo/3ve7kP7P0X7g4kCWj12EzTORYNieXtyRlKIVoLxgE6WeMKAgQHJC0eQWwUgwRsuEAQXxC74Xcyjtt@CPEEJIEz0fOjsOD6WdNVhlsV7ponxHVLjvsFLc2wCegBfaUAyaX4e4aE2@Gdzq761aZtApH4zm5CflQywTiQm1LQ9MCHpxoubH69c0mg0iJy61GfNLUcI0izSDzX545zQIsBKIhVoExgDQxYjoK@VD1OLtGxrOBRXoWIrpOtAlBd6gUCh8gaAaPg6zOUhQySKclHhsQubZNyp3s5SHMgvwogEKCf@04bZRDpMJObWZGnFdoFe6OHFIO9ebmksq0F@h2C8dLQnrzMdAhbyX2ssJ4T2f4h2u2Pp37rrjuXntnO4evquPjw7R17IwXkYYX3wGGglatWs1kx7S1taJ3I@FVCLq@IrTAnrANaVy7xPUZwePj86@fX07Hzl9JhDKg/BFKK0GuWOblTa3XlDeWDzM5E@OzbPXz07nglymaq86yFV6yZ/SNgjyN6J6tsqKt6xgsi2fnbiRQFgLSOL8sAS4HNRGVjBqmp303a30eqEhRX0X9f9tKNglPDXHNDqpPyHHQpZ42BOZjXFi@gazOM7Z9Z6hhDel@XT61lFEo@Gqy2zx25MPMuUjEWtUi6qjXvUauJ8Xchghh78RP6maMuAd4HLlVbKPMuEiJ12NKfk3si5sJHnU7Gz4z9PoSEk9YnnCuiUO1ex/@O/pYAdwEm22DTARgQWlMf3Rrd8HwDLfF426Xm8okaT25yDec85Czz9YkYPLvrFgSE4Idg6w/YjHfrelUOb7QmZH6d97yzRSGPfy1Q8xJsYuL8CblQNGbAbPsMzwMZuNz9wJLNzwTI/WjwbgbzOopgs9rQv2Kz1GrY15MUIJgcLYOTXUQBwfX57zdDDM/LnSIfBIEdlRkQbsKg5D0bQqwN2Y8gmPW8AUULVKuBQfrHtxaEk1cqwF1XAhwpR/RFrQcuC@V0HqUsSo21qeGGPTVRlrGh7XZQOvFfG724UTV6xAX6amx/t9h4e687WPs3yRTg/El1eOLOEBZDnByoQRPDHdniMDhsFD2z64E8sDMFkVCA7AAMhdAR8Jlpl9ovPyvz3OUt@4V/y85mHUeJIufMjiIVF0@FbEmcKAeFjh3SyTr8TYlRwbs0/mIbp3KlFv3lrQiDXWmpx2LTLtVK5XAxLajHEUPb0Ke5kpkWIlJeGbMgTANKLvuaAPCGyNouhU6QNtdhrVkt8BDyWy9odDPiWmsZdkU7N4lMITBV4kwjrUIuphuqwDMOeAn2ooaJZCWh8p8pEnuDPnBB90SuXkQajeIkEfDM752XupjrnJt87OXmCZA6CmRnfM4bffivYW5CrT9WovF@tbRzoRDZLnRc3jtKm/arxuXt2fXb2F62jKoXnp7K9KTslUyqYJevrtml@/PgRcgaitXWl21Zb29ulirO1U6ocOIpdObAt29bUalU7J086m6Hz5MkT1T5TlHpNOf@AB/P7G/CP/8Fn/ojXDf4mf81BVj8bGlE/T6RC6wkYSW1r4@DJR6kgFS5bZfgY/Fou7@0d6Lo@ga9R3pcKHxsA0@hOp@VGu9EwWq1JS@@22lLhTipMplKhKiP3JanQnDRe8wnaL/KZyp9fwqWhd9vx2cujw/OjSrWhF6ovTivV8zfPCjY81OdP2FWDp9dHhy9O31xUqmLIH0/eHr05Oz587nlenPZ6aS8adlsHB2UDCDwwWl2gZPJLuVVuZllG3l@WDJpIhRetyRtTbwD2l1LhNYfVOxpAf5UK7UJb3a/uVy3furHsa/v6VXS6@Ds9hffexPoUJdbQGtq9g9Ot003bticWe2PdWrcTK4hO7R40GfyzAmh6Vn9iDazQCm373mSP/wWn0avTCKaKYFg2sTKc1erDfXB6@gom6wP2T/DPsywkcmLdwJ/l2/zz4dLSLAm2gt36Vlzd@tzmTqW@222ziZd1ZVJROm2l6xTMtNMxhRXLVTBE7J5OLy9fHF4cXl6auDeaNIrlg7J@AJ9mq9zIb/uFXgvFZjQkRYXtWtxRIEZQh5eUinju27a75eId3RtN0QWRkl3SuPuoW45TOszbm9DOmzuOw1LqchIcRdCkqgzinSrbnUm1T6oyDyO7sIjtWqOhbtW1VmurDo9bO5quWti5qX2w511VLUpkZSJHiULupuKfejdtqPyj4T9Nw5f5taXdqQ0AAZi6xp/FAFUj2vjdu3f4fTe@GYsWb4h37@adyw@8AZ@bR8auNmCHCBGXKIVpAV1ySDbrGiT4TNvcUnfKu/m/5oYG5Ms1pQbky0pBmumraReQXalgOK9luyorqD8Hi1WRzwwf0ujariTDR2pesYEXSo3WnQQR5wqyiDHZtiCj8H2akKjf35CoJ7ogesK2A3beKfN93L9h8jiOEr83hoQG4WArnRCK/wkAVlaaMvgEZ5SNGBuPRmM2/zz30j366RON0d1BALQkA4NVtbq7U9/ZrVV3Kju7O5t1e6ter9jVir29s71rVcDl7dhbO/Vdu7KzuVvb3Nzchd767rZUYGHP65sm@BZblglv9Fgfi3WjHSLXdjqWPH8TkxSSnKivxIpu74925K1tea8Ed3lfrkFT3q4DMGRp@MOIBv6EJDKGLSLhr4GICg6ZkDtcRWqsOaMdZwrYZlzM6SCwHgyDwFfXJewX4UGVt6sy0RQH4JyVMcn1HuxiE0ylOThkmlu7Mr4GEDED2bKlwlTq4cHn5q6DrnXaaElFBYlTalJBr0WbUaFYLIInvmjJNfnUaJi5j22Z3Md20OeinzOkJk4MVlCQC2TiLf46Avzeu//9X5Qi7YX0a1S3v4W/OoW9WKltKrVOsyDWuL2tFVrVbSOlt4WueEfUzW2NwBN3DVW70B/zz3xlrayzpdaa5/FNwEMOkLHzh95g4FX/8OrjV9hzKMq8FmVvfdMb4q8Bl@engjp5qy5rYNVp@uHywyUEwzqRq3WZkLJJYP9i/qUK9ru7u7WzVZB@M83v7Vygd5549RnkJKNgXeZ1mHivKJaKwnn2BY1XI0jR5wZK0EIxpx227r/jVnvvFf/fHvBOQrrQYFRsgId2K7x@RUrcW3c1cjerfarYi@U3bV6tS1g2SkJiOaKqilN4zrwJWHB1kSYC8OIaOGXVa9oO8Ro4GdwhP8sx4Gc2otzEJu4LOBVeV3Ok5TIkp6QFo5doWRpfLgvwqSBL8OMGPcG26Js/AnkBHte4aj5aewDQtroAo3QsJWfzZ9iABFydz1Ahv5uNB@MhFdVmPHESFp35@4UqplIpqwSOhGyXYkf6k@pqd5giO9@Cp0/dD3E76Dpa0MzwXi4HzlS6Vj0BUsqaQVO3nRiIdbJ2uex1m4H2JzXmxAdNC4ABN86candzTYfNXF2pVvnSDvVvYbdy3A7LdrcyqpTeN79UaNOqTOALYqv4lc8gvJko1az5pRw6tAFfzNbvSSJupmXq3K8Ow5Br1W9@adNu09IcHwaWy8fADNCZtv1yuasBch86Vwc6/tOntOy3Jo6v6xpCfajtH7czaHTLTXzeU2ljsv@lPYLxeyrcm4DG14B4GHdfBzAf0OeAjIX6FqQLGidI3gTIC5rN0vv90vtSc2PjS3uiB92KEP@etVA8Ej9B4pdtRC29XzYsLhJ@fKPKv3h7vxillMgVsD4QciVeGikoLL2HnnixGqb/Aw)

Languages that are not on Tio:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use python 2. Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse (#73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway (#74) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)

Languages that use abstracted interpreters in the test driver:

- V (#2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)
- Alphuck (#44) [local](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master)
- What (#71) [local](https://github.com/gimmetehcodez/what/blob/master/what.c)

Other languages:

- Japt (#7) was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Surface (#66) [local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip). Tio Surface interpreter is no contest because it was created after challenge was started.

### Explanation

This answer is based on Chance's golfed version of #74 ([chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38063449#38063449), [tio](https://tio.run/##zVvLdttIkl0bv9CbNMgyAJEACFKSJfEhybbU4@pyS2PJdp8iaRkCQRIWXgWAImWZPrOdObPofW9m2f/R2/mK/pGaG5ngQyIlV52ZxdAikEBGZjwzMiKSvrTT4a@/FujDTiP/ZuBHGcvcNGO9xLt2E4O9uGEHtpduVWuSxKGSqDdyvHDAsqHLvDAeZazv@W4qOXbGWizOZzGowQosce2eAJP6UcJoCAuufOYxJ47ZpW8PDYf5HmCPKzuAT6OAYDI3iRMX15SFrttjaew6Xt9zOC7mTjI3TL0oTA3mOVds7Pk@67k@BiwIcMqYjI3SpVcCnSH1Ionh48T3yJ0/FV3AhO6MZTe2E85yxGLO/4zzcWLHMYiUCuwMhGde4KbMy5SUuXbqkRwxJHXDHpdWPJdwxOxwmUt27dnMBr2jhM@dukkG9gw@Lxu6iYspbUI@SOyAqePEyyACEuYhO3XthJ0nrqsBC5Tgpo4dg447KIEsIgwZMWJwZTUaytHJsQKliRGGHWdSIamd/@uPks2MJite1PFtynJdOvrzK3Zb7FAbVGAyKDZOVFtjzW8sNTsdF9@JdWkOkqmEWSVIxWdmFGcmZraTDOQtWvp11Yj9JbSscU8TS4YkoHrQBXsdsvdlzpczShIXVCxEal@BZT8KB5AmWE1GIUkjZNsVKMCJwl5aZu41ZBaFQkPRmMv3fOhBZSkpxL6EeGyHJC8WARcnlgEsL5fnDG8a@SMOh5FpRuYHmWAozfi6z96zvu35NAT9NJWgOnHTkZ/RmFHYI70HXuj2DDYjw4l6BBRE10BnY1L@AusmWFptnCgAQw0RZ5W6/vnXv/UGA8xz6DhR0suN9T3rRc4oAME2J9aGIZK5RqHtc7IAVybsYjgQXNu@17MzQh/e5Cg4ERzrOBr5PRYBYTL2sLCG9jUWY7/vOpkrTDwaZaCxzAL7SvgIT9gtGA/sSyiWI@C4Ods6O3gJLTmuMBg9GGX9HabHR0xJzY/q/p66/7TjgjbN0DaKpjmow9qMDf4KT8pjhvP@cKFPsp5zL6JV5MfDEXwGesI0hjdJSJiODXZScioZ/F6ZXXJBc08EQ@dLdOwqicsusa5njHEbETZA43Vat/kMC53O4O6amNtbsjBYJ4wsS1echB@NgZjTRs4TNh0ScntgA1WWM3QoGBIY@Zu7rF2FsHSa7dJlO/qlB@2QHcDV5MpY4hHgtaqAwWxCe0uLIrBvMIsjXPRCk8zrQ8kB7Da5YY5LiwGrwhV@jpCMuGGkHuwo6rOKXt3a@o7ys8Q81H82bf2L@aiOifl7aj5kfXfMfDscjOwBDDkKMcR2HDfO8hUETtIMa@S@G@Qv9dynG@lQKh7cx819W@7tl3CQ9xHayz20TWYPQQUQte5jlTM7GfCVyHpegvXi39zHDoDre8jlTwRyh4BP8gMkzDYmGJk7cZ1RhuUGQx4PPWcI2yXqQrFghXe8jx6vlrHD5ej9OWoixmo9q0qGOX9FZDw4hU4aXZ0HXp@mat15wZW//OLxme00WDNxNCcRHmrprWHaBmwvFxp28zOKJOD@Zls3X1nz8GIuTwj4R9qYEveXERQGe/YGIYHY4XzbX/KMXhoq2Cq81IPUaQMnWz9/fUL7wQdXxDCQu9jLlp15hIgGw/MNmjpmSpBcZxgxPWRKToMq8/30M8gy08ThDX0piJA1A3JSSV68azbRZxGb3d9QWWsVjqNUyqwty90y9jA/hQmFI9/HwyjkS0x1tVvYmuOmqYEFA9kaFI2AOrnkatO7gNkwicbMnWp1ZR2636mQl6NLb/L/UCMO0SWu4GpJDfzVb9HDCuBMEbKci24FgsvuZRSQn2cfOMdE74sEe0Mf@4EU32RDeDrdYbLdjGIXJN3xJAroRHCuanUe0CmK8TnyQvVWefr0qbKntJQyWvtoNai1T60SWvu8pfMWwRnU4iPKvEW9bT6C3nWVaXs280TrkmonFLV@8WLVbu/t1bplu23l9yrdNWwm2DsArdMN8yhas0lNTZNbYzBqXPYlwf45lPMTQj72k0c7cR8B4iJxkObIOpIshFG760vlRU9VxKrvzQDiM@Kb9VGEvDwVH/DGC68islEzmLUuKoa1dWcK5DurI/teOuSXO6ArZK328NFpcNnnlzUAe3kYgJiCciSSC3dlFIlEESx/zMGCKIwEKZCXF9rmW34zsHuso@euk75DzAsXa37g6rs189ILzUu3/xDk8YsXrzlM//LSewgIQiG6Z/c1YMnocp3MEJsNVzZxdkfq56Mk8/WemdHd/e9/60H6q7oZ2jcpovmreeMCQiM96f0HVZUPpQd@Wa/WzyMfmd535nBsiuBtf95YP9cee@vC9qHWkCd4oNT34U8gMvi5VePGuvBHPXd2Xz8pl@HdWECMDr1Ah2VvGxWuQDxSfMO9zwOz3AtoxDSU@CR@ZPdMkYp67kKjQvbuxB5E4Y25tLMZyeVvIHUWc7BF7pkNR9lIXCnh/J7uvJi@jy3IHLKydfjCOspvD8CDiO2HbFcsG3LV@rFvX5mX1Lzoo7meVcFM4g2Q3c7uD4F9OIttxzXHKd0e9B/hKI25InnrITBEj4kvrg@BeKGDnTVcNB4CBIs@v/weq@NG4Ng@TK8mDI/qPfqSjLx7UvXtyxvaz4a/34AI66BUYnq0yMIW5aQ4fniQ4zAdjqfp7O6uHy0qT3wCJ0LC7H5vJ8J24gXgu9pbaj5oGV6kL5K@VJgTBQHrPJB9bSMo8O0UBpLlYnavoRZ@ecxgaZ9wRr6dLFqPmes9omaJ90O522Jk7DkRdnRhn/Tge2tNNKRg735gtJiGqor8shhKT7nvfIXYh7bfb4860MjJKGV6wHZ@g08S2Qrlg0t2YUQPCc2JxvR9cNkOo2tXXNfvRV/WUvUbfI7uc5NAxL06vOd8z1o/eCk8Di7rfeHVWqoyx1/7fo@9iaIE6WrKqkblUfWsNeYz47Xxk3FinLEzz4/SR@WBZD1NxXW9KS9ALxPPDnWHbHi5vX7YWsL4vsYO@fUBBdv@IPK3dwamjcta2ZyNkj459sfE8riPsqzv@qh5KBOFVn5/0K1f4e979kGVEPhxj2KaeXO9rXzHoeUJwMNsIuqnketZPK7szE0sSdcLEbhzmMPEGY7tm8dEzdOQt7zWPC/@pOW8RI53XpKXRNP5qUPhdegkLi8FzZJbVqAC1SiAR82ixGAcTlXtUknTJDGI1uYgBNgMild@qfgmisopg5PMOCwSqHabFW8ne5U9a8qaTN6TWbcrZuVloKNJzEu2b8XQdtHuNouKritFpRPusYrCQV1k/@tB7TtwfY/fBJ0L1lloB7zeR@0Zp3VRVIQHo0ry0A57iB/fhR7P250oEaUxUX/lsfo//t7LC@wDF0wGXmr7EAQdCUWBO4zG@wJvjv0wjm0q0NMcCFt8kdnrLw9ZOvYyZyjq6nCw747Pd/KiaH5EhYdTChyXqBBKRRdS0szOhNIENb3IFVaRI56PmjGFXWsUhGzs9bJhasAVhY7Li66zQiAoSQgszJKIrKrMXrOeSzEUL0x8HkG3fhRd8XoIUfKPv4tSMDo9MiFqz9Dzs4kljAxey@L1V8eJRqB6NskXN4lyEJWEjL13BIncwKZd8V5jztDmNWpYoj6r0BIaUaV9eXjG9COm0MkaFWzrXl8tHr794/t2pdv8xgITaZVJNSIuN/kH/bmVymU2A6lPya6WuyvoXvQqTC5O5JwtOsXhhxZzoxKrianU5uqaVVwDfgDE7c4d84orL6uHFFrQyUqYYn3gUeNTi0XTLKrIxwIvY/pZxrbo@NGFSNASR0aMDvSoekhDihP2lQ3JVnSHWVsVPAmB@FSwDpqLLHi5DGG@ci9HPFy/rhrVWpOzU7xoNlq8lbi9iI402h87466ZzqTS6Ux@qFQnEFuUAPyZSSvn6M@vbotGq/L1awqnJMtTpc7LRLS8i7enr0@Pzs4Pz9@dQYxTwWXhOEoCe@EiyAhiH7vHMPL5GRHkkXhu@n238YT7DelJDqiqrGizBrMqDB7qydyx5GKVdbkomqKPe5J5373O3H30PZa7OnbKtZ0rVkmX3Vx5ZgAkPKzJEfzqjHgYzu0ad8XZkVkTDOlgiIPPCZ4/rWPsbi@HFwLfp2cIPWdjGYqzuoBaD0S8CuCcbgEjiFzLxPT/iPIY@8j3KSeo71EOYOl72JcQHx@@/mkV8RJOAljpn9vG0nH80QT7Ozxgn9s2HfrMLCbKD@1mLgEefygqyba/cGrpvChMNtQnl@xjVdNy4ClzSsuakQcx2KGfwoX2evAJlzcZuRT4UlEHnheD5QJYN@Y7XJnJEsGmzdXDG7iMMaIw55MYXORwfOZ03flnxzX/@de/iTPPTob2v@ftPtr/KdofTRLQ6iGZoHEuGhLL@9enLMU@JRgP7MkST7RV0FbkhSNERQEkeM0FQuCC2AW/i3nU9nvIE0qAMMnnkZvj@Nykqw6zLN4zTdrZEdP2DV5IcyfQA7ykgTDQ/GVER9DwzOb21vamZYJI/Xo2IT/ZGFBVR0yoaXuwH@nai5ufLh3WaDSYnDq27za360KQZtH@WJM/zQktAlYSQUCbYQyGLEagr5UPU4t2ydJoKK0/xVJYt479XegFW4TKGwDR6HWYy0PGHhTloqJDEneScXd6MwtuEFmEEQtITvyHCLOJdEwk5tZkacV2QS96eOnGuxNVGstqkD8QGC/07MnrTIfBQv5rjeWEaP@HaLc7Ff1bd90h@tx2DlfPytX7J93ECzs4CyOq5h2DVqZWzWrNtLa1pXUi51OBWloVXzEl1gHWleN6n6M4PXx59PrHk9OzlbNeDqncB1OY0mqUOrpRbnfnDeWezc9E@uLYPHvz4ngmyGWq8q77VK2b/D5hDyD7IGplq6h4xwoiq/JbJ15k7msZWeT1S4AvRUq/glXVbqftbqPVCQsr6L@u@yFGwdig316g1Un5zzAUtsbBvJ5VAM@jK5jHIyfMekYQ3pfls@ZZ/ZAOcqsts@dem3TyKBmLyqJcVBt3qNXEabiQwQw9/ET@pmjJwLvA5Ugr9ZllQkSOHM0puTNyLmzi@UTkdPzHJHaIcD7xHAGdcucqMj/@ywfE/q@zRbqAFAQLyuNZ0Q3PALDM5/WOnsdLYXZyk3Mw7zlzA08/n9FDi35xvAcnhKQXiUc69L3Lut1sT9j88Ouxkz8jjX0vU@nIbWJQZgVuVI0YsBq@Syd2jd1ufjzIZqd4JX4QeDqCvE6jmC2y2VfurPUWCQ17NcLksACX/TgKANfnt7cueXiX/TnSMRhyVGZEtIFFzXkwgt4WsBtDd9LzBtglVK0Mh/KDZS2OEG2thCxUgQ8VovojFXGWBfO7jj2XJGa3bcMLe@5EVcaKttcl6eC9Mv5wrWjyig3ws9f8ILZ3/xB2tvbtLF@E8wPM5YUzC1iAPD/@wCZCP42jQ2@kCB5s@uBPbhjCZFSQHcBAmD0Cn4lWnv0@szz/Nc2SX/iX/DTl/i5xpNz6EfbColnnyUh9ig3hU4d1sk6/E9KuUL8x/2AaZv1WLfrNGxMbudZSi8OmVaptlErFcEMthrSVPXtGOcy0iJ3ywpANeQIgvehrdcgTO2uzGNaLdkMt9prVDT4Cj6WSdosB31LTuC3aU7P4DBtTGW8SYR1qMdVIHRXDsKagjzRUNMuBHd@qMpMn9KMkQl/0SiWiwSheEAHfzM5ZibupzpnJs6Z6HiCZg2BmxneM4ddfC9Y2ovSpGpX2q7WnBzqTzY3Oq@u60rb7VeOX7unV6elftI6qFF6eyNamXN8wpYK5Ufn63DQ/ffqEmIFpbV3pttXW8@cb5fr2zkb5oK5Y5QOrYlmaWq1qZ@xJZzOsP3nyRLVOFWWrppx9pGP0/af4x//wmT/S9Sl/k7/mIKufpxpTf5lIhdYTGElt@@nBk09SQSpctEr4GPxaKu3tHei6PsHXKO1LhU8NwDS602mp0W40jFZr0tK7rbZUuJUKk6lUqMrE/YZUaE4ab/kE7Vf5TKVffsKloXfb8elPR4dnR@VqQy9UX52Uq2fvXhQsPGzNn6irhqe3R4evTt6dl6tiyB9fvz96d3p8@NLzvDjt9dJeNOy2Dg5KBgg8MFpdUDL5odQqNbMsYz9fbBh2IhVetSbvTL0B7D9JhbccVu9ogP4qFdqFtrpf3a9W/Mp1xbqyrt5EJ4u/kxO89yaVz1FSGVaGVu/gZPtk07KsScV9V7mp3EwqQXRi9dB08a8SoOlV@pPKoBJWQsu6M9nDf8FJ9OYkwlQRhmWTSkazVvq4D05O3mCyPrB/xj@vUiEiJ5Vr/FV8i38@XlS0ioQksLu1HVe3f2lzp7K12227Ey/ryqysdNpKt14w007HFFYsV2GI1D2dXly8Ojw/vLgwKTeaNIqlg5J@gE@zVWrkt/1Cr0ViMxqSoiJRizsK9gi7zotJRTqlbVvdUvHW3htNyQWxDWtD4@5jq1Kvbxzm7U208@ZOve6mtsNJqCuCJlV1sd@pstWZVPusKvNtZBeL2Ko1Gur2ltZqbW/hcXtH09UKdW5qH615V1WLElmZyFGisNup@KfeThsq/2j0T9PoZX5tabdqAyCA2dL4sxigakwbf/jwgb4fxtdj0eIN8e7DvHP5gTfwuX5g7GoDGSJ2XKYUpgVyySHb3NIQ4Lva5ra6U9rN/zWfaiBfrik1kC8rBWmmr6ZVIHalglF/K1tVWSH91alMFfmu4SOMru1KMj5S89IdeKHUaN1K2HEuEUWM2fMKIgrftxMW9ftPJdsTXdg9kXYg505d36f8jYLHcZT4vTECGoJDKp0wm36yj5WVpi4@wantjlx3PBqN3fnnpZfu2Z8/2zG5O2yAFcmgzapa3d3Z2tmtVXfKO7s7m1vW9tZW2aqWrec7z3crZbi8HWt7Z2vXKu9s7tY2Nzd30bu1@1wquGHP65smfIsly4w3em6fynSjHSbXdjoVef4mZimCnKivxIpu7Y925O3n8p5cew4IhGb024UG/cojMoYtJtEPdpgKL8zYLS0dNdbqU8w/o3uOmWEFGAbDV9cl6hcbgio/r8pMU@qAq6@MSa72kLcmFDxzcMSW27syvQaImIFtW1JhKvXojHJzt07OdNpoSUWFKFNqUkGvRZtRoVgswveet@SafGI0zNyrtkzuVTvkZcmzGVKTJobeC3KBTbzFX0eA33n3v/@LUqK9kH6Ntqxv4Y/1wl6s1DaVWqdZEKvaeq4VWtXnRmrfFLriHVM3n2sMT9wZVK1Cf8w/87W0srKWWmuex9cB32RAxs4feoOBV/3Dm09fkWUoyrzuZG1/0xvir4HLyxNBnby9JWuw4zT9ePHxAtvfFpOrWzJjJZMhYzH/UoXF7u5u72wXpF9N87FcBb3zUKvvIgoZBetircPEe2NTcSicx1tovBkhKJ9bJyPzpCh22Lr7jpvsnVf8f2PgnUR0kcGo1IBPdsq8YsU2uH/uaux2VudUqZdKbdq8Mpe42SgJWaUuKqg0hVefN4GF1hNrEgAvp8ENq17TqjOvQZPhjogsx0Cf2YhSk5qUCXAqvK5Wl5ZLjpySFkYv0bI0vlQS4FNBluDHCXqCbdE3fwR5AR3NOGo@WrsH0K50AaN0KkrO5m9hAyG3Op@hzH43G/fGI/jUZjxxEhad@fuFKqbSRlYO6hKxvRHXpT@pjnZLQXH9W/DsmfMxbgfduhY0M7qXSkF9Kl2pngDZyJpBU7fqMYitZ@1Syes2A@1PasyJD5oVAAM3zZxqt3NNh81cXalW/tIO9W9ht3zcDktWtzwqb/zc/FK2m5XyBF@IreyXf4HwZqJUs@aXUli3G/hSfH5HEnEzLdn1u5VgDLlS/eaXtt1tVrS6j4Gl0jGYAZ1p2y@VuhqQ@@hcHVj3nz2zS35rUvd1XSOoj7X943aGRrfUpOc91W5M9r@0Rxi/p@LeBBpfA/EYd1cHmA/01SFjob4F6YLGCZE3AXlBs7nx8/7GzxvNp0@/tCd60C0L8e9VFoon4idE/LKNqBs/LxsWFwk/qlHlH7y9H4yNlMllWB@EXI6XRgoKN35GT7xYDdP/AQ)).

#### Adding C++11

I am using a variant of the trick with utf-8 string literals (introduced in C++11) (see also [#67 C11](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124702/70292)).

```c++
#define u8 "x" // some non-empty string
puts( *u8"" ? "C++03" : "C++11" );
```

#### Incident

Only incident broke as a result. This is because of three `u8`. Fixed by adding `u8;` after `puts(p);`.

Answer (score 10):

## 86. Miniflak, 2440 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#~
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<\>@*99[?]*]*.*|!)'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
' (<><       (          )> ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};

" }"';           (( ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main ( ␉){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003836 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2526 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl
**86** in Miniflak

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbdtpKls/Rmj/ol7LEiSRANzC@IMD2SZyenD459sRO0usAcYQoQLEuRBIGh5A1rzNrHvq9X@ax/6Nf5yv6R87sXSUBNtjJWTOz1oCRSlW7qvat9t61S@45yei33yT8kPPIvx36UUpSmqSkH3s3NNbJj7fk2PGSWqUqCAwqjvoT1wuHJB1R4oXjSUoGnk8TwXVS0iLjbBQdC0QiMXX6HEwYRDHBLiS49olH3PGY9HxnpLvE9wD2hXkA8EkUIExK43FM4ZqQkNI@ScbU9Qaey@YidJbSMPGiMNGJ516Tqef7pE996LBCwC3DYGSSrFXx6XShHwkEPu74HrrLpwIFmJDmJNOxEzOSIzJm9OeUT2NnPAYkBYlcAOKpF9CEeKmcEOokHvIRuiQ07DNujZccjogTrlNJbjyHOIDvJGZjJzROgTydjUtGNKYwpIOTD2MnIMo09lJgATLzhJxTJyaXMaUqzAJCoInrjAGPO1PCZBHOkCIhOhNWoyGfnr2QQWi8h@6MU0GKq5f/8pPgEL1JClc2/JqiaAunvzwn80IHy4AFDAaCHceKo5LmV5IYnQ6F38zqGcN4IcCoAnDFJ0Y0Tg1HGwOCWgoIGg4WsaTdVPSxvzYxadyTxZoqcag@SIO8DMnbMqPMncQxBTxWTHWugWg/CofATyA2noTIj5DsmSACNwr7SZnQG@BaFHIZRVPG4cuRB0JLUCRODxjkuMh7vgwYQ2EhgO5lHM3nTSJ/wuCgZ5KiAgJXoCuO@HJA3pKB4/nYBdpxKI51TJOJn2KfSdhHyQdeSPs6ydFwoz4CBdENTOfAoKwCVk6wtt4YUgAMgogYqdj0j7/8tT8cwjgnrhvF/Uxd35J@5E4CQNhhyDqgiqiwUej4DC2AK@PsvDtMcOP4Xt9JcfrwNpuCIcFmnUYTv08imDCeerC0Rs4NLMfBgLop5UoeTVLAsUwC55pbCY9rLhAeOD0QLJuAzc3I1sjxM5CSS7nKaMEkHRwQbXxK5MR4rxzVlaOdDgXcVF0tFgxjaIO@6UVWBU/yY4rz9mQlT9SeSy/CdeSPRxOwGtASJmOwJzEy03WAnATNSgqWr0x6jNHMFoGqs0U6pXJMSQ9Wdk4Y0xGuA9hfw5WbjbCSaQ53V8Vof03DQDtBydJkw0z40RQmZrih@QSdDnFyZ@jAVGlG0AkniM/Iau6Sdh2CpuNoPUoOtJ4H0kE9AGOTCWONRgCvVjgMjMalt7YoAucWRnG5kV5JkngDEHIAehvfEpfiYoBVQbmlw0kmTDESD/QoGhBTq9Rq3xB@Ghsn2q9gPT4bj8oYib8n5hMyoFPiO@Fw4gxBkaMQujiuS8dptoKAkiSFNXLfELJKLbPqejISCsf352bWLbP3a3Og9eHSy2y0g2oPjAqA1ZoPq5w48ZCtRNL3Ylgv/u392QHg5t7k4gcEuYPAB/EBFHLXBEpGZ9SdpLDcQJGnI88dge4idiFfsNw63p8eqtZnB5OjDZZTIzJW62lF0I1lFaLx4BAaSnRzHLD6OFTrTgUT/nrF4yM7SbBl4GiJIliotVrdcHTQvYxp4M8vMJYA85c7b7aylgHGkp/A4J/QMcX00wQEBvrsDUMEccKl41@zjF4SyuAqvMQDrqMLR12/fHmG/uAd5VEM8J37snVjHkFMA90zF40NuRAE6o4iooVEznBQROZRPwJaRhK7rKCthRGiqgOfFOQXa8oH@sijs/sOlbQ24diUcpm0RbFbBh/mJ6BC4cT34WESsiWmUHUOuubSJNFhwQBvdYxHADuxRNXFXcB0FEdTQheqLW@b7ncK5Nmk583@H0rERbz4FahaEwOr@h45bADmghDFjHUbEIx3z6IA7Tx5xyhGfH@MwTcMwB8I49t0BJZOc4noNKMxBZTuWBIZ8ITwXFFtFtLJsv4x8kJlLu/s7Mh1uSWXoXQEpQaWjrBUgtIRK2mshHA6lliPMitha5v1wLquvGjnI8/ULop2hnHrZ2@sOO16vdotO20ru1fwroIzAd8B0BreYBxZbTaxqKpiawqE6r2BwMm/BOH8DCEf@dlDTzyAAHG1dRCWk3UEkTOjeteWiquWCo9Wb4wA2KePb7dHEeL6UKwDBHDXEeroqnRl6lbtzhCw49nsOfCSEbvcAd1Aa7OF9U6C3oBdtgDUszAAYgrcJSFfmCnDSCSKQPOnDCyIwoijAvzyQsd4zW46eI9t@Nw10neQ6VFY80Nq9LwQy98A0w4PGOSg1/MeAgW@IOr5fQtYPOltYxuEZ6MNP07uMD6dxKlP@9n9v/61DwLYFM/IuU0goL9eFq6AbygqbfCgtLKu@MAu2yX7ceLDdu8bY7gOBvGOvyxsH6tOXlNQf5BsyHZ5gKkPtGGEA6ZuU79hafiTPs3v2wdlPLwbDvDeoRcwycEdYxtmeR7ofi@Y4f1x0xP7kdM3@EbUoytRcqbTmTOMwltjzavpce87cMzjDbLaeaajSTrhV9xsfkto3hh/jy3GDNKsOT2LGlHi9LwHOIhI7D2ktHwtoJnWBr5zzYtXWNxOKicm9oaws83vD4FBtAcB@dhxqTFltwftRzhJxkyYrPTIeLHPrw@BeKELnjVcFR4CBDJ9dvk9KscUwYV1gKhiskdbY5F3j6m@07tFVzb6/fqDEw5LJaKB7Wi6pZJZJVq02out0krj8cP9XTfrf3i4vTfPQLEB3Ai2zfRb/gicihc4vlbprxUftK@561@Vtpkf58aBoMB3ElCQNGMzvQGxsMtjSot@wp34TrwqPaKyK3TyLfdDu7ZVn7HnRr6XaWb@sGWCEMO8@yHRahjMKLLLqis@ZSbzOUQ96Hi/Pmo3IzfFzdIDqvMdFonvU3AnuKYLevQQu9xoir8HF@wouqH8ut0Ffd6K1XdYHM1nygCx9mb3vvstDcU8ELtst4TXW7FKXX9rfZ28iqIYNqoJqejmo@LZqsaJ50cJuWDXx3gBW/Qk4dftCrzONs8JNXfEl9WyvL3bVqSYRyMn7PqAcB1/GPl7B0PDgcuDGjCJB2jYs/v3GrWlUbKsbxqlZfgShVZ2f9CaX8Pft5QDEyBgvj2MY5bF7YryoAXLIv6HCYQwHxNe24l7YR4sNStO6KMqVScnsTuaOrePQn3LczzE5txz1DFZzwLh/9k0u49P0/8@K7Ux7P7jw94R77VPwUyz64ZQScW0fmcPyzS/32YN/Amd0K025Kz3kYLifHdQ/ChSZkZGnXy@9h8d87vQRi@OT/cQ59vZ1@zMYplETMrZYQvUeXGWWk@W51fSy9CNKUsp5kkSImGicxKAZ06jWCcMTlGcUklVBd4JLf0wBLAcip0gYBKXH04kBFxuymBhI95uk8J8Vjfr1oI0iVgXSbfLR2XpxNPZmKX@X/Ou7YLTbRZkTZMLciesE1NmoNSHhbcV1LkDN/DYjeO5Ip2ETsDyxljOKbV5chr8IZ5IjJywD3uRN6HH8j9uFPMUK8/jX@JG7@9/62cHNUMKRAZe4vjACDxcjAI6iqZHfN5s9pPx2MGDHhwDwl@fZ4i0ZyckmXqpO@LnM@Cu37y4PMiS69lhJzyc4yZkDQsuVGgaAA5OyoXGselHlOtUNvGyV04UxECTICRTr5@OEh2cW@hSlrzPE8qASYxgYRpHqJNl8pL0KcbiLMH1cQKy9aPomuXVEJO//40fKUCjhyqE5Xx6dsa1NiMBnbZYHt91owlgnQ/ymcZRBqIgkyGSmwBHbmFFUF6vEnfksLMO0EQtz/TjNDzb/@zkgminRMYzWkz8295AKZy8/uPbttltfiWBAXtzA3ONjG/iD9q@lYhlkoPYC9Sr9WYTmletMhELMzEjC08D2eHXUqn4aiIKlpm48sx9wA4Smd7RKcvcs@OZEANVPKELE1gf8KiyofmiaRYU2NQHXkq0i5TU8CCbAkugxI8eCR4NYxYauxRm5AsZoa5oLrFqJjxxhvh48BE0f8zTJNX1dJbxnPYmbOt3U9Er1SYjp3DVbLRYKab9CI/G2u87066R5FzpdGY/mJUZsC2KAfypgSvn9Jfn84LeMr98ScDXieJCtlm6EZd3YX7@8vz04vLk8s0FsHHBqZReRHHgrEwEKsHYhyBkFPnsrBH4EXs0@bbZeMLshvAkA1QUUnBIA0w/AQv1ZGlYMraKmljgRd7GLMmy7V5jZj4GHslMHTln0s4EKyfrZq6cKwAyD9bkBOxqjjwoznyLuWLkiKQJBGlAEANfIrx82kbY3VYGzxl@hM/A9IyMdShG6gpqOxDSyoEzvDkMR3IrEYv/JczH4Ee@jTlCfQtzABa@NfvaxC9OXv785vXp5txr02YwGyBLDVl7veN0BsEj2MEB03A8Qsz1JsqOgHPDAHZ/xM8lHH9l2pLlEQNq0gANsw9rGxcFS8AkuLgJ2hGdnPgJGNJ@HyxD7zZFwwIWlZ8qLI8WRAkYoC/9XJmIAsImzc2jQDAcUwju3Q@8c4HBsZGTbafpHWr84y9/5SfonRTK/5aVB1D@D15@byCDNo9cOY5L1iBb3r48Jwl4K0544MzWaEKHgQ7JCyFE8wLg4A1jCIJzZFf0rsZR2m@BnyAEYCZaPjR2bD4ad5VRmo7rhoH@HfZKA53lZOkM5AC2UofdhfFpgi80gH029mp7u5YBSGo3@YDsnGyIeUI@oKrWQYWEG2/c/NBzSaPRIGLiOj5t7tmckUbBeV8VPywRLQCswEOBNoE@0GXVA9paWTel4JQsFbviKpQtmXRt8PJcLuAoFFYAEBWrw4wfIniiKGMVHrnRWcqM6m0e4kB8EUYkQD6x11rygTQYiI@tisKG7q7ygXgOsqbN@roYxHcIdoFgdXGb6hDQkP/cojkhlP@dl9sdU/va3fZKxlJ3TjbfvFDuvzeBtJDjizDC/PALwJUoFaNSNaw9dW2diNlQgC2uii8wJKwDWFcu9T5G4@Tk2enLn87OLzbeHGCQ8n0wmcitRqmj6eV2d1mQ7@l8ztIfXxgXr358kTNyHaus6T5W2wa/j9gDk73jmdfNqVjDxkSW@b0Ds2NC7QXbiWwhZNlqrAE@42mijVkVdb5odxutTihtTP9l22s9kl7EN3mg1EnYSz0y2WJgXub55MvoGtTjkfcVtBQhvM/rby7k2Wh8LaDSMvr0xsBzbEFf5anFgtK4g63K363gPMinBzuR1RRgJ9giq7lcYSPnt44IT71ES0zu9FwyG2k@4zs79mqSE0JQH3suh06YceX7P/YeDewAXqarTQNsRHCny/ZGt2wfAMt8mUPreyy96sS3GQXLlgsaeNpljg8u@tVhMRihKE5h@5GMfK9nO832jCyPUh87R9aTse@lCh7gznTcXwE1iooEWA2f4vlv47CbHTaT/Ey4xI6VzyfAr/NoTFZ72uc0L72GbQ15PoHBQQMo@WkSANyA3V5TtPCU/BJp0Bn4KOdItGEWJaNBD/o1mF0f0VnfG4KXUNQyGJQfLGt1IO2oJdiLymBDOav@iMnBdcb8rkP0NY45bUf3wj6dKfJUVutd5A7Uy9N3N7IqbugAO8nPjvX794/087XvpNkiXB6Hry@cPGCBybMDNXAi@KIlvkIBGwUPdPr4TzQMQWUUQDsABSHOBOiM1XL@vm95@W7Wml345@x87r6XOJXnfgS@sGDYbEtiL8AhfOiQTtoZdEL0Cvat8QdDN@y5UvCbtwY4crWlFEZNq1QtlkqFsKgUQnRlT5/iTmZRAE95pYu6OAMgreCrNvATPGuzENoFp6EU@s1KkfWAx1JJnUOHr4mhzwvOwig8BcdUhpqYa4dSSFQUh6nr1gLwQwkVjHLgjOeKSMQZvuKG0xe8Uglx0AtXiMBXo3NRYmaqc2GwvZOdBUjGMMjV@I4y/PabZO1BrL5QotJRpbpzrBHRKHae39hy2xlU9E/d8@vz8z@rHUWWnp2J1q5oFw1BMorml33D@PDhA8QMRG1rcrettPb3i3Z576BYPi5bctmWiG@ZlqUqlYra2Q0vyBP7yZMninUuy7WqfPEe38s42oEv@4PP8hGvO6wmq2Ygm58dlSifZoLUegJ6Ut3bOX7yQZC@CtJVqwQfnV1LpXr9WNO0Gfz00pEgfWgAEIRCUqvVXSxKjXajobdas5bWbbUFaS5Is4UgVURkQ1GQmrPGazZK@3k2XOnTz3BpaN32@Pzn05OL03KloUmVFyfPypWLNz9KFjzVVo/YWMXH16cnz8/eXJYrvNcfX749fXMO9Z7njZN@P@lHo27r@LikA6LHeqsLyMx@KLVKzTRNya9XRd2Jd8/2zo4F6Xlr9sbQGoDFz4L0mnXQOip0@SJIbamtHFWOKqZv3pjWtXX9Kjpb/Z2dQb03Mz9GsTkyR1bfsqyZSd@Yt@btzAyiM6sPRQpfM4CiZw5m5tAMzdCy7ozz8F9wFr06i2CoCLqlMzPFUc0B3IdnZ69gsAFM/BG@nmkifjPzBv5M32Kf91emagqwLezW9saVvU9tZmBqh902nXlpVyRludOWu7ZkJJ2OwTVarIBSYvNicXX1/OTy5OrKwH3SrFEoHZe0Y/g0W6VGdjuS@i3kmN4QZGX67t07/L2b3kx5iRV43btl4/oDK8Dn5oG@dwuKohc3vwfWoV6CQum4XevOFyqB75OObMucIEWh4DgV0erMKgNSEZk/OgRrYFUh5lf2amqrtVeD570DVVNMbN1V31uNRtZUUaNYlGdiFMtkvuBfZb5oKOyj4ldVsTK7tlQFmtUaPM3myqyhNBSsgyrsNV@0sMjg5lBqK2pXXSx4HVwVtcHHbKlAMkb8/0d/UQLbUyJLCwk9QEh2ayrsJ6i6u6cclA6zb3MHiFHEqlwFGkXZkdvt42K1uL/bPuoWu0Wl0WkdFw8P@ZNe/LKjypKQq03TkpBvgqTbr0WrIsqoRjbmzyKf6j5E9tVDQYSPIBOl0Wpke3RllSNQW0Sdk4xLRF3MQapZEzgCJctxdToz02Tgdq9ZmEvOwhYEkSzEJTBPgsPIimyzxKc4FwtO3La64kIszHsL9JRFS2U@rrZr28VdXt4/sG1oKGYtJrRkRWigieOylQKmGVVBBh6pQrNHh14ogDPvAZunZN@EYM33nZhEg8EOr4eoBLZzFLwy9X3cF2NQPo1ivz@FQHFHkBIKn@DcoRNKp5PJlC4/z7yk7nz8CMHmGD0HxBKmoKPfr1QOD2oHh9XKQfng8GC3Zu3VamWrUrb2D/YPzTK4jgNr76B2aJUPdg@ru7u7h9BaO9wXJBr2vYFhgHW2RJGwAkSs@HZQA9@jivRRiwhSnw4wFfrEV/rqE6m/rJgcELF60DE7pijgq3PA5SfqHA2NQhKILaMBUczyBNZW7WhyIO7ti/Ui3MUjsQpFXyGmDMIT5Y4oqu3D7pG4X4Oh6uDNNPmpdUTE/UOxLu7vQ6VqLwC7nOol3gTMj64T@GmagO3cMyviPix22QYwm3f5p7U@8XU9SZ0YdzEMHIL8vUMRqwGk0ar1ivWypZWP@WBkzxKkhdDHdxF2D230a7DUGy2hICPNclWQtGq0G0mFQgG84WVLrIpnesPIXFzLYC6ugy4P3Yuee8yWEFPMnfbxH2u4tTqoqTZWJkIT6gUb1ockSrez1afDh2x8ldg5MzmfY0ore@e2/grwUZz6BXu/qg2r5usvnj8/qGotFh9CnLogCyRGSr5ENetr@JMt1cdydVeudpoSx8HaV6VWZV9PnFupy@uIsruvEnhi6l@xpMGUfZaGfMOsr5W2PE9vAhYAABoHf@gPh17lD68@fIGtoCwDNdbeV63B/xpweXbG8RL3aqIqJUny/ur9lSRINSJWaiIhJYPAftL4cwUWweHh3sGeJPxmGI/tJKF1GQgPKMSIk2BbJHwSe68cTN2Fy2gYCq8msGVaLhKCqwT3GKPW3Tq2cu5Usf@9gjoB8ULFUbDgxEO3zPKJpIhvzbW7KpnnuWgFWzEdqi6zpzFNJ3FITJtnuXEIz14WYRZcdqSJACzZCa5N8ZqWTbwGDgZ3iJezGfCT9yg1sYj7NIaF11VtYT0tzDBpQe81XNb6l0ocfMHR4vS4QZ@TzduWj4BegMdnrpL1Vu8BtM0uwMgdU87I/B4yYEOkLEcok99Nxr3@sDVQc5oYCqvGrH4lioVQTMuBLSDZxbEt/Elx1TluWeyvwdOn7vtxO@jaatBM8V4qBfZCuFY8DlJMm0FTs@wxIGun7VLJ6zYD9U/KmCEfNE0Ahrlx5ESdLyUdNjNxJWr5czvUvobd8ot2WLK65Um5@Gvzc9lpmuUZ/IBtZb/8CZiXs1JJm59Loe004Ie7pzucGDeTkmPfzdZDl2vFb35uO92mqdo@dCyVXgAxgGfS9kulrgqT@9C42dH2nz51Sn5rZvuapiLU@@rRi3YKhW6pic91xWnMjj63J9C/rsC9CdP4KiAP/e7KAMYD/GzgMRffCnWO4wzRmwF6QbNZ/PWo@GuxubPzuT3Tgm6Zs79urgSPyM8Q@XUdUYq/risWYwkLNRTxB6/@g15MiFgG7QMml8drPTmGxV@hZbxaDYv/Bg)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)

### Explanation

Miniflak is a Brain-Flak derivative, where `[]`,`<>`, and `<...>` are ignored.

Here was the Brain-Flak code before I started

```
[][][][]
((([]{})))((()<<()>>)()<<()>>){}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())
<>{(){
}(((({[]}{}))))
(){(()()[])}
()
}<>
()
```

Here's what Miniflak sees

```
((({})))((()())()()){}{}{}{}({}(((((()()())){}{})){}{}))(({})){}{((())({})({}{}({}){}))}({}){}({}())
{(){
}(((({}{}))))
(){(()())}
()
}
()
```

Miniflak's first problem here is that it can't escape the loop that Classic and Flueue s live in.  This is because those two languages use `<...>` to push the zero used to exit.  Since, Miniflak can't see that it never pushes a zero and thus never exits.  Miniflak's equivalent operation would be `(...)[{}]`, however `[...]` prints in Classic so it is to be avoided.  Instead we add on `{({}[()])}`.  Since Both of the existing languages have already pushed a zero only Miniflak enters this loop which will decrement until zero.  Once Miniflak leaves this loop it will act just like flueue and produce an 82.  In order to differentiate the two we add a `<()()()()>`.  Since every other has `<...>` this does nothing for most the languages, However Miniflak sees this as `()()()()` or `+4` bringing us up to 86.

The last problem is the block comment.  Previously `<>{...}<>` had been sufficient as a block comment for the flaks, however Miniflak doesn't see `<>` so it has to be modified to accommodate.  The shortest block comment I could come up with that works in all of the languages is

```
(<><()>){({}[()])}{...}{}<>
```

So I swapped out the old one for the new one.

#### Prelude

Prelude took issue with all of the new parens I added to the block comment section.  I had to add *a lot* of new spaces to satisfy prelude.

Other than that all the languages were fine with the addition.

Answer (score 10):

## 88. [PingPong](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PingPong), 2539 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.arxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)';
""""
' (<><         (          )>  ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};

" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main ( ␉){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");"eg_0 ' ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxx"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}              @:8:8\\
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3   \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003725 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2626 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTtdd9pIls/R2X8wL2VBRxKgLzA2RoDtTuzZ9HTa3thJ5gSII0QBivVBS8LgEHL2dffsw7zPyz7O/5jX/RXzR3rvrZIAG2ynz@6es7ItlapuVd2vuvdWXblnx6PffsvhRc5D73bohQlJaJyQfuTe0EgjP96SI9uNq@WKIDCoKOxPHDcYkmREiRuMJwkZuB6NBcdOSIuM01E0LJAciajd52DCIIwIdiH@tUdc4ozHpOfZI80hnguwp0YN4OPQR5iERuOIwj0mAaV9Eo@p4w5ch81F6CyhQeyGQawR17kmU9fzSJ960GGFgFOCwcgkXqvi02lCPxQIXM74HrrLtzwFmIBmJNOxHTGSQzJm9GeUTyN7PAYkhRy5AMQT16cxcRMpJtSOXeQjdIlp0GfcGi85HBI7WKeS3Lg2sQHfScTGjmmUAHkaG5eMaERhSBsnH0a2T@Rp5CbAAmTmMTmndkQuI0oVmAWEQGPHHgMed6aEyUKcIUFCNCasRkM6OTuVQGi8h2aPEyEXVS7/5SfBJlqT5K8s@GuKoiWc/PKSzPMdLAMWMBgIdhzJtkKa30isdzoU/mZmTx9GCwFGFYArHtHDcaLb6hgQVBNAULexiCX1pqyNvbWJSeOeLNZUiUP1QRrkVUDelRhlziSKKOCxYqp9DUR7YTAEfgKx0SRAfgRkzwAROGHQj0uE3gDXwoDLKJwyDl@OXBBajCKxe8Ag20He82XAGAoLAXQv5Wg2bxx6EwYHPeMEFRC4Al1xxFcD8o4MbNfDLtCOQ3GsIxpPvAT7TII@St53A9rXSIaGE/YRyA9vYDobBmUVsHL8tfXGkAJgEETISMWmf/zlr/3hEMY5dpww6qfq@o70Q2fiA8I2Q9YGVUSFDQPbY2gBXAln591hghvbc/t2gtMHt@kUDAk26zSceH0SwoTR1IWlNbJvYDkOBtRJKFfycJIAjiXi29fcSrhcc4Fw3@6BYNkEbG5GtkqOXoCUHMpVRvUnyaBG1PEJkWL9o3xYlw93OhRwUzSlkNf1oQX6phVYFbxJjynOu@OVPFF7Lt0Q15E3Hk3AakBLEI/BnkTITMcGcmI0KwlYvhLpMUYzWwSqzhbplEoRJT1Y2RlhTEe4DmB/FVduOsJKphncXRWj/TUNA@0EJUviDTPhhVOYmOGG5hN0OsDJ7aENUyUpQcecID4jq7lL2nUAmo6j9SipqT0XpIN6AMYmFcYajQBeKXMYGI1Lb21R@PYtjOJwI72SJHEHIGQf9Da6JQ7FxQCrgnJLh5NMmGLELuhROCCGWq5WnxB@EunH6gewHl/0R2WMxN8T8zEZ0Cnx7GA4sYegyGEAXWzHoeMkXUFASZzAGrlvCFmlmlp1LR4J@aP7czPrltr7tTnQ@nDppTbaRrUHRvnAatWDVU7saMhWIum7EawX7/b@7ABwc29y8ROC3EHgk/gACplrAiWjM@pMElhuoMjTkeuMQHcRu4AvWG4d708PVeuzg8lRB8upERmz9bwsaPqyCtF4cAgVJbo5Dlh9HKp1p4IJf73i8ZHt2N8ycLhEESzUWq2m2xroXso08OcXGEuA@cucN1tZywBjyU9g8E/omCL66wQEBvrsDgMEsYOl41@zjG4cSOAq3NgFrqMLR12/fHWG/uA95VEM8J37snVjHkJMA91TF40NmRAE6oxCogZESnGQReZRPwNaehw5rKCuhRGiogGfZOQXa8oG@syjs/sOlbQ24diUUom0RbFbAh/mxaBCwcTz4GUSsCUmU2UOuubQONZgwQBvNYxHADuxSJXFXcBkFIVTQheKJW2b7ncK5MWk587@H0rEQbz4HahaEwOr@h45bABmghDFlHUbEIx3L0If7Tx5zyhGfH@MwDcMwB8I49tkBJZOdYhoN8MxBZTuWBIJ8ITwXFYsFtJJkvY5dAN5Lu3s7Eh1qSWVoHQIpQaWDrFUhNIhK6mshHAalliPEitha5v1wLqutGhnI8@ULop2hnHrF3cs2@16vdIt2W0zfZbxqYAzAd8B0Co@YBxJaTaxqChiawqEar2BwMm/BOH8DCEf@dlFTzyAAHG1dRCWk3UEkTOjcteWiquWMo9Wb3Qf2KeNb7dHEeL6UKwDBHDXIeroqnRlaGb1zhCw49nsOXDjEbvdAd1Aa7OF9Y793oDdtgDU0zAAYgrcJSFfmCnDSCQMQfOnDMwPg5CjAvxyA1t/wx4aeI9t@Nw10neQ6VFY80Oq99wAy0@AqQc1Bjno9dyHQIEviHr23AIWTXrb2Abh2WjDj5M7jE8mUeLRfvr8r3/tgwA2xTOyb2MI6K@XhSvgG4pKHTworbQrvrDbdsl@nniw3XtiDMfGIN72loXtY9XJGwrqD5IN2C4PMPWANoxwwNRt6jcsDW/Sp9lz@6CMh3fDAd47cH0mOXhibMMszwPd7wUzvD9ueiIvtPs634i6dCVKznQ6s4dhcKuveTUt6n0Hjlm8QVY7z2Q0SSb8jpvNp4TmjvHvscWYQhpVu2dSPYztnvsABxGJvYeUlq8FNNPqwLOvefEKi9tJ5cRE7hB2ttnzITCI9iAgH9sO1afs8aD9CCbxmAmTlR4ZL/L4/SEQN3DAswarwkOAQKbHbr9H5ZgiOLAOEFU87FHXWOTeY6pn927RlY1@v/7ghMNikahgO5pOsWhUiBqu9mKrY6Xx@OH@jpP2PzjY3pufQLEBnBC2zfQpfwROxfVtTy3314oP2tfM9a9K28yPfWNDUODZMShIkrKZ3oBY2O0xpUU/4Uw8O1qVHlHZFTrZlvuhXduqz9h1Qs9NNTN72TJBgGHe/ZBoNQyeKLLbqiu@pSbzJUQ96Hi/PWo3QyfBzdIDqvMdFonvU3AnuKYLWvgQu5xwin8PLthReEP5fbsL@rIVq@@wOKrHlAFi7c3ufecpDcVzIHbbbgmvt2KVON7W@jp5HYYRbFRjUtaMR8WzVY1j1wtjcsHuj/ECtuhxzO/bFXidba4dqM6IL6tleXu3rUgxj0aO2f0B4dreMPT2akPdhtuDGjCJBmjY0@f3GrWlUTLNJ43SMnwJAzN9PmjNr@H3KeXAAxAw3y7GMcvidkV50IKlEf/DBEKYjwde24k7NWpLzYpi@qhK1clx5Iym9u2jUE95jofYnHmOOh7Ws0D4fzbN7uPT9L/PSm0Mu//4sHfEe@1RMNPsviFUUjbM39nDNIzvt1kDb0IndKsNOet9pqA43x0UP4qUkZJRJ1@uvUfH/C600Yvj26M2x/ZcWOdPxjB1cg5B9Hn4@AaAbZTfsGzI8ngyLqVpHKhzo/TQPl5mxnKvAiei7LAyO34hOTxCnfjg85Mw0giDk2W7WFQUgXdCHzIMACyDYrkJPB7maY@YgDNPGCxs8dttkp/P6kbdXJAmEesi6Xb5qOyg8mQ2ZkmFN7xrO293m3lJVaW81AnqxJAYKPVgSW8Fte/ADVz24HiuSCeB7bMTaSxnlFr82Bs8LeY6RnbQh13O28BlJ0tOGPHDW54huMQt5N//1k9TQEMKRPpuDPIbBpi2DH06CqeHfN509uPx2MYUEo4BgbXHz57UF8cknrqJM@KZHwgE3p5e1tJj@zSNCi/nuL1Zw4ILFZoGgIOdcKFxbPoh5VqRTrzslREF0dXED8jU7SejWAO3GTiUpQWyo2rAJEKwIIlC1KoSeUX6FKN8dnT2eQKy9cLwmp3YISZ//xtPVkCjiyqE5Wx6lj1bm5GAtpssQ@A44QSwzgb5QqMwBZGRyRAjToAjt6DTlNcrxBnZLIsCmqhmOQSchucRXhxfEPWESJj9xZSC5Q7k/PGbP75rG93mN@LrsOvX8RST8U38Qd03Y7FEMhBrgXq13mxA86pVImJ@JqZkYZ6RpdWWSsVXE5GxzMSV5QR8lqJkekenLCfAEj8BhsCY@wtiWB/wqrCh@aJp5uWJ5/puQtSLhFQxRU6BJVDiSU2CSWc838Yu@Rn5SkaoK6pDzKoBb5whHqZU/OaP2QFMZf2gTH9JexO2qbwpa@VKk5GTv2o2WqwU0X6ISbf2x860q8cZVzqd2Q9GeQZsCyMAf67jyjn55eU8r7WMr19j8KKiuJAsdpCJyzs/P391fnJxeXz59gLYuOBU5k7DyLdXJgKVYOxBeDMKPZbFBH5ELo2fNhvPmN0QnqWAskzyNmmAUyFgoZ4tDUvKVlEV87zI25glWbbda0zNx8Alqakj50zaqWCleN3MlTIFQObBmpyAXc2QB8WZbzFXjByRNIEgFQhi4EuEl2/bCLvbyuA5ww/xHZiekrEOxUhdQW0HQlo5cIo3h@FIbiVi8b@E@Rj8yNOYI9RTmAOw8NTsaxOfHr/6@e2bk82516ZNYTZAlhqy9uHIyQzCUrCDA6bhmJzM9CZMk8uZYQC7P@IZD9tbmbZ4mbxATRqgYfZgbeOiYEc7MS5ugnZEI8deDIa03wfL0LtN0LCAReX5imXSQswBA7SlnysRUUDYuLmZZATDMYVtg/OJd84zODZyvC1P36H6P/7yV56b7yRQ/re0PIDyf/DyRx0ZtJnM5TguWYNseffqnMTgrTjhvj1bowkdBjokN4Dgz/WBgzeMIQjOkV3RuxpHbr8DfoIQgJlo@dDYsflo1JVHSTKu6zr6d9iFDTR22ktnIAewlRrsW/RfJ/ipBNhnfa@6t2vqgKR6kw3IMnBDPIHkAypKHVRIuHHHzU89hzQaDSLGju3R5p7FGann7Y8V8dMS0TzACjwUaBPoA11WPaCtlXaT83bRVLArrkLJlEjXAi/P5QKOQmYFAFGwOkj5IYInClNWYTKPzhJmVG@zEAfiiyAkPvKJfTCTDaTCQHxsRRQ2dHd10ogZljVt1tbFIL5HsAsEq4vbVIeAhvznFs0JoPzvvNzuGOq37raPPZa6c7z5TYd8/4sMpIUcXQQhnjyfAq5ELuvlim7uKWvrREyHAmxxVXyFIWEdwLpyqPs5HMfHL05e/XR2frHxTQKDlO6DSURqNYodVSu1u8uCdE/nM5b@eKpfvP7xNGPkOlZp032stg1@H7EHJnvPz3Q3p2INGxOZxvcOzBKQ6inb42whZNmqrwG@4AdQG7PKynzR7jZanSC3Mf3XbR8M5bQCfiMEpU7MPheSyBYD8yo7qb4Mr0E9HvkSQk0Qwv2y/k1Eds6NHxyUW3qf3uiYIRe01Qm4mJcbd7BV@FcbnAfZ9GAn0po87DFbZDWXI2ycJq4jwg91wiUmd3oumY00n/GdHfvoyQ4gqI9ch0PHzLjy/R/7Qgd2AK@S1aYBNiK4h2Z7o1u2D4Blvjyd67vs4NaOblMKli0X1HfVywwfXPSrNDQYoTBKYPsRjzy3Z9nN9owsk7SPZai1eOy5iYyp4ZmG@yugRlaQALPhUcwsNw66aRqbZNnmIktYn0@AX@fhmKz2tC9pVnoD2xrycgKDgwZQ8tPEB7gBe7yhaOEp@SVUoTPwUcqQaMMsckqD5verMLs2orO@OwQvISslMCg/mOYq1W0rRdiLSmBDOav@iMeO64z5Xen5NY7ZbVtzgz6dydJUUupd5A7US9P3N5IibugA@0Yg/WCgf/9jgWzt20m6CJeJ9vWFkwUsMHmaqgMngp9w4scZsFFwQaeP/kSDAFRGBrR9UBBiT4DOSCllXxKXll99rdmFf04zf/e9xIk090LwhXndYlsSawEO4VOHdJLOoBOgV7Bu9T/omm7N5bzXvNXBkSstOT9qmsVKoVjMBwU5H6Are/4cdzKLPHjKK03UxBkAqXlPsYCf4Fmb@cDK2w0532@WC6wHvBaLyhw6fIt1bZ63F3r@OTimEtREXDvkfKygOAxNMxeAH0oor5d8ezyXRSLO8OM5nD7vFouIg5a/QgS@6Z2LIjNTnQud7Z2sNEDSh36mxneU4bffcuYexOqHexU5PCxXdgo5kjsS9ULn5YcPL24sqW0Pytqv3fPr8/M/Kx1Zyr04E81d0SIFXcjpBePrvq5/@vQJQgfSbmktrau0Vanbllv7@wWrtFcrlI5KplSycsQzDdNU5HJZuejsBtYzuGTzXJKqFeniI379cbgDP@wXruUr3ndYTVrNQDavHYXIv86EXOsZ6Exlb@foGaBEi@yq14@IkPsm5ITcp8YnIQeBUK7V6i4WxUa70dBarVlL7bbaQm4u5GYLIVcWkQMFIdecNd6wEdovW3yo4q/AzZ/h2VC77fH5zyfHFyelckPNlU@PX5TKF29/zJnwVl29YmMFX9@cHL88e3tZKvNef3z17uTtOdS7rjuO@/24H466raOjoqaq6pHW6gI@sx@KrWIzSRLy4aqg2dEMr92zvbMjIfeyNXurqw1A5Wch94b1UjuAXEeBvl@FXDvXlg/Lh2XDM24M89q8fh2erX7PzlArxP2aGIZHAOLOjM9hZIyMkdk3TXNm0LfGrXE7M/zwzOxDkcKP4UPRNQYzY2gERmCad4Z8@Nc/C1@fhTBUCN2SmZHgqMYAnsOzs9cw2AAm/gw/rmEgqjPjBn4Nz2TXxytDMQTYK3are@Py3q9tZnWqB902nblJVyQlqdOWulZOjzsdnau5WAYdxebF4urq5fHl8dWVjpunWSNfPCqqR3A1W8VG@jjM9VvIQK0hSPL0/fv3@Pd@ejPlJVbgde@XjesvrADXzQN97xbwfLNd7c4XCoGfZx3JkjjSskzBY8qi2ZmVB6QsMkd0AGbArECwL@9VlVZrrwrvezVFlQ1s3VU@mo1G2lRWwkiUZmIYSWS@4D/yfNGQ2aXgj6JgZXpvKTI0K1V4m83lWUNuyFgHVdhrvmhhkcHNodSWla6yWPA6uMtKg4/ZUoAsDPX/j37DGPalRMotcmj6A7JbVWAjQZXdPblWPEh/mjtAjCxWpArQKEq21G4fFSqF/d32YbfQLciNglbotLqze5ci5YRMQZpmDrkn5DTrjWiWRQkVxsLjs9CjmgeBfeXAkuTC/atmHhQLxaN24eCAT1YofN1RJEsQ4RIkIjdajeUpgrw6UFBa8DcnKWuJspiDKqRt4Dbk9ESs05kZBoO3es38PGcvLEEQyUJcAvMjcza4LFnsoFSci3k7aptdcSHm570FetaCqTCfWN21rMIuL@/XLDDlZiFtMaAlLUIDjW2HLSKw3qhBErBWEZo9OnQDAZx/D6QzJfsGBHeeZ0ckHAx2eD1EMbD9o@DFqefhPhqD@GkYef0pBJY7Qi6mcPnnNp1QOp1MpnR5vXDjuv35MwSnY3QxEHsYgoZxQrl8UKvWDirlWql2UNutmnvVasksl8z92v6BUQLvUjP3atUDs1TbPajs7u4eQGv1YF/I0aDvDnQd7LkpioQVIMLF75Qa@EVXqI1a4B76dIBHp89mcl95lusvKyY1IlZqHaNjiAJ@xAdcfqbM0QbJJIZYNBwQ2ShNYElWDyc1cW9frBfgKR6KFSgy4cxkYkggQ1HqiKLSPugeivtVGK8Obk@VnpuHRNw/EOvi/j5UKpZIh1cGkYhoLQDZjAlLMggYKk0j8KeqArZzxy6L@2AyJAvALN7ln9b6RNf1OLEj3AQxcNgj7B2IWA0gqXq2qr1CvWSqpSM@JNkzhdxC6OOnErsHFrpHMBuNlpCXkBFSRciplXA3zOXzeXCqly2xIp5pDT31lC2duckOek70TlrmeFtCRPEAto//98MtX62qWFgZC02oFyxYOTkxd5uuUnRTHT5k41uOpcHJ@Xx5MJd@F1x/DUjJdv2CfQPWhhX17RfXm9cqaotFmhDxLgh49wW5cx3Va/VapwM6@TWsmt@Cn6xcfSxVdqUKOtNmjiNo7iu5Vnlfi@3bXDdN9ci7@wqBN7ZgymZuMGXX0its@Ii10pb36Y3PggzApPaH/nDolv/w@tNX2GxKEiFmfu@b2uC/Dbi9OOMiksW9qqjk4jj@ePXxCgKcKhHLVZGQog4hmq7/uQzr5uBgr7aXE37T9cc2q9C6jLUHFMLQib8t2D6O3Nc2ng4Gy4AbCq8nsCtbriuCCwu3MaPW3Tq22O5UsX8cgzoB8UK1krFgR0OnxI4sSQE/@Wt3FTLPjrtlbMUTV2V5QBvRZBIFxLD4QToO4VrLIsyCK5U0EYCpDDhR2W2aFnEbOBg8ISRPZ8Ar61FsYhG3ggwLt6tYwvrJM8OkBb3XcFnrXyxy8AVHi9Pj@H1ONm9bvgJ6PmboHDntrdwDaBtdgJE6hpSS@T1kwJ5LXo5QIr@bjHv9YfehZDQxFFaNaf1KFAuhkJR8S0CyC2NL@JPsKHPcFVnf/OfPnY/jtt@1FL@Z4LNY9K2FcC27HKSQNP2malpjQNZK2sWi2236yp/kMUPebxoADHPjyLEyX0o6aKbiipXSl3agfgu6pdN2UDS7pUmp8KH5pWQ3jdIM/oBtJa/0KzAvY6WcNL8UA8tuwB9u0O5wYtyMi7Z1NyEAXa5lr/mlbXebhmJ50LFYPAViAM@47RWLXQUm96Bxs6PlPX9uF73WzPJUVUGoj5XD03YChW6xie912W7MDr@0J9C/LsOzCdN4CiAP/e7KAMYD/CzgMRffCnWO4wzRmwF6frNZ@HBY@FBo7ux8ac9Uv1vi7K8bK8Ej8jNEfl1H5MKHdcViLGHxiSz@4NZ/0AoxEUugfcDk0nitJ8ew8AFaxqvVsPhv)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)

### Explanation

Wow, it took 2 full days for me to produce this answer. This challenge can be really challenging.

#### Adding PingPong

PingPong is another 2D language. It follows the path of haystack - deflects from `/` on the first line and
continues to execute from the last line on the same column. To separate pingpong from other 2d languages I use `$` to skip over `\`.
PingPong code is `@:8:8\`. Second `\` is there for retina.

There were two obstacles to adding pingpong on the first line: 1) `}` terminates current thread (and hence the program as we have only one thread) in pingpong 
and 2) `@` terminates the program.

`}` was there for brian & chuck. Solved by refactoring brian & chuck.

`@` is there for hexagony. Solved by jumping over it with `#`.
To prevent `#` from changing current ip (0) in hexagony I used `*`. Second `#` is there for Algol.

Note that pingpong interpreter returns nonzero exit code, but this is not an error - it just takes the value from the top of the stack (the situation is similar to snusp).

#### Brian & Chuck

Old brian & chuck was on line 6, mixed with surface.
After removing that code I moved surface to line 4.
New brian & chuck code:

```
?63
x>.>.
```

Brian immediately gives control to Chuck with `?`, Chuck then prints 63.
`[]` are there to hide b&c code from bf/smbf.
Note that ```` ``` ```` on the second line is not needed for b&c, but removing it breaks pip, which I cannot fix easily, so it stays for now.

#### ><>

Behavior of fish interpreter is ambiguous: when it encounters invalid command it prints error and terminates the program, but returns exit code 0.
I am more inclined to treat it as an erroneous termination. So I refactored fish code to terminate cleanly. It was previously intertwined with
underload and whitespace. (fish is `\4n;`, underload is `(22)S`)

#### 2D languages

2D langs realigned as usual. `ZZC` on the first line is a filler to align `v` (tried several letters to satisfy trigger/japt/05AB1E/pyth).
Klein 201 and Klein 100 are moved to line 22 (parens are for underload, quotes are for coffeescript).
Klein 001 stays on line 19, but needs right padding.

#### Incident

Incident gave me a lot of trouble, so here are some tips on fixing incident (see also [answer 33](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107166)):

```
x1   ...      x1x1 incident code x2      ...      x2x2
                          | 0mo must be in the middle (even_count/2 or (odd_count+1)/2)
```

some tokens in incident code may accidentally detokenize, incilite to the rescue

Currently:

```
1:?2 ...skipped... 11:?2 12:?2    13:0l 14:0v ... 41:0mo ... 53:0v 54:0l    55:^_ ...skipped... 80:^_ 81:^_ 
                                  |           incident code            |
                                       note: (81+1)/2==41==0mo
```

Other langs are fixed as usual.
I added 91 bytes for the code worth 5 bytes. Sorry about that, too tired to golf.

Answer (score 10):

## 90. [RunR](http://esolangs.org/wiki/RunR), 2585 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.xxxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main (  ){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003545 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2671 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTtNd9pKluvozD/oTVniRRKgLzA2RoDtl9g9ef3S9sRO0idAHCEKUCwkniQMDiGntzNnFr3vzSz7f/S2f0X/kTf3VkmADbbzzsycM7ItlapuVd2vuh9VcteJh7/@KuFFzkP/duCHCUlonJBe5N3QSCc/3pIjx4srpbIgMKgo7E1cLxiQZEiJF4wnCel7Po0F10lIk4zTUXQsEIlE1OlxMKEfRgS7kNG1Tzzijsek6ztD3SW@B7CnZhXg43CEMAmNxhGFe0wCSnskHlPX63sum4vQWUKD2AuDWCeee02mnu@THvWhwwoBtwiDkUm8VsWn04VeKBC43PE9dJdvOQowAc1IpmMnYiSHZMzozyifRs54DEgKErkAxBNvRGPiJXJMqBN7yEfoEtOgx7g1XnI4JE6wTiW58RziAL6TiI0d0ygB8nQ2LhnSiMKQDk4@iJwRUaaRlwALkJnH5Jw6EbmMKFVhFhACjV1nDHjcmRImC3GGBAnRmbDqdfnk7FQGofEeujNOBCkqX/7bT4JD9AbJXdnw1xBFWzj540syz7WxDFjAYCDYcaQ4Kml8I7HRblP4m1ldYxAtBBhVAK74xAjHieFoY0BQSwBBw8EilrSbkj721yYm9XuyWFMlDtUDaZBXAXlXZJS5kyiigMeKqc41EO2HwQD4CcRGkwD5EZA9E0TghkEvLhJ6A1wLAy6jcMo4fDn0QGgxisTpAoMcF3nPlwFjKCwE0L2Uo9m8cehPGBz0jBNUQOAKdMURX/XJO9J3PB@7QDsOxbGOaDzxE@wzCXoo@ZEX0J5OMjTcsIdAo/AGpnNgUFYBK2e0tt4YUgAMgggZqdj0z7/8tTcYwDjHrhtGvVRd35Fe6E5GgLDDkHVAFVFhw8DxGVoAV8TZeXeY4MbxvZ6T4PTBbToFQ4LNOg0nfo@EMGE09WBpDZ0bWI79PnUTypU8nCSAY5GMnGtuJTyuuUD4yOmCYNkEbG5GtkaOXoCUXMpVRhtNkn6VaOMTIsfGR@WwphzutCngpupqPmcYAxv0Tc@zKniTH1Ocd8creaL2XHohriN/PJyA1YCWIB6DPYmQma4D5MRoVhKwfEXSZYxmtghUnS3SKZUjSrqwsjPCmI5wHcD@Gq7cdISVTDO4uypGe2saBtoJSpbEG2bCD6cwMcMNzSfodICTOwMHpkpSgo45QXxGVnOXtOsANB1H61JS1boeSAf1AIxNKow1GgG8XOIwMBqX3tqiGDm3MIrLjfRKksTrg5BHoLfRLXEpLgZYFZRbOpxkwhQj9kCPwj4xtVKl8oTwk8g41j6A9fhiPCpjJP6emI9Jn06J7wSDiTMARQ4D6OK4Lh0n6QoCSuIE1sh9Q8gqtdSq6/FQyB3dn5tZt9Ter82B1odLL7XRDqo9MGoErNZ8WOXEiQZsJZKeF8F68W/vzw4AN/cmFz8hyB0EPokPoJC5JlAyOqPuJIHlBoo8HXruEHQXsQv4guXW8f70ULU@O5gcrb@cGpGxms9Lgm4sqxCNB4fQUKKb44DVx6GadyqY8NcrHh/ZiUdbBg6XKIKFWqvVDUcH3UuZBv78AmMJMH@Z82YraxlgLPkJDP4JHVNEf5mAwECfvUGAIE6wdPxrltGLAxlchRd7wHV04ajrl6/O0B@8pzyKAb5zX7ZuzEOIaaB76qKxIROCQN1hSLSAyCkOisg86mdAy4gjlxW0tTBCVHXgk4L8Yk3ZQJ95dHbfoZLmJhybUi6Slih2iuDD/BhUKJj4PrxMArbEFKrOQddcGsc6LBjgrY7xCGAnFqi6uAuYDKNwSuhCteVt0/1GgbyYdL3Z/0OJuIgXvwNVa2JgVd8jhw3ATBCimLJuA4Lx7kU4QjtP3jOKEd8fI/ANffAHwvg2GYKl01wiOo1wTAGlO5ZEBjwhPFdUm4V0sqx/Dr1Amcs7OztyTW7KRSgdQqmOpUMsFaB0yEoaKyGcjiXWo8hK2NpiPbCuIy9a2cgztYOinWHc@sUbK06rVit3ik7LSp8lfKrgTMB3ALSGDxhHVhsNLKqq2JwCoXq3L3DyL0E4P0PIR3720BP3IUBcpQ7CcrK2IHJmlO/aUnHVUuLR6o0xAvbp49vtUYS4PhTrAAHcdYg6uipdmbpVuTMEZDybPftePGS3O6AbaG22sN7xqNtnty0AtTQMgJgCsyTkCzNlGImEIWj@lIGNwiDkqAC/vMAx3rCHDt5jGz53jfQdZLoU1vyAGl0vwPITYNpBlUH2u13vIVDgC6KePbeARZPuNrZBeDbc8OPkDuOTSZT4tJc@//HnHghgUzxD5zaGgP56WbgCvqGotP6D0kq74gu7bZfs54kP6d4TY7gOBvGOvyxsH6tG3lBQf5BswLI8wNQH2jDCAVO3qd@wNPxJj2bP7YMyHt4NB3jvwBsxycETYxtmeR7ofi@Y4f0x6Yn80OkZPBH16EqUnOl05gzC4NZY82p61P0OHLN4g6wyz2Q4SSb8jsnmU0Lzxvj32GJMIc2K07WoEcZO13uAg4jE3kNKy9cCmmmt7zvXvHiFxe2kcmIibwCZbfZ8CAyiPQjIx45LjSl7PGg/gkk8ZsJkpUfGi3x@fwjEC1zwrMGq8BAgkOmz229ROaYILqwDRBU3e7Q1Fnn3mOo73Vt0ZcPfrj844aBQIBrYjoZbKJhlooWrXGy1rTQeP9zfddP@Bwfbe/MdKDaAG0LaTJ/yR@BUvJHja6XeWvFB@5q5/lVpm/lxbhwICnwnBgVJUjbTGxALuz2mtOgn3InvRKvSIyq7QidLuR/K2lZ9xp4b@l6qmdnLlgkCDPPuh0SrYXBHkd1WXfEtNZkvIepBx/vtUbsZugkmSw@ozndYJJ6nYCa4pgt6@BC73HCKfw8u2GF4Q/l9uwv6shWr77A4ms@UAWLtze499ykNxX0gdttuCa@3YpW4/tb6GnkdhhEkqjEp6eaj4tmqxrHnhzG5YPfHeAEpehzz@3YFXmeb5wSaO@TLalne3m0rUsyjkWN2f0C4jj8I/b3qwHDg9qAGTKI@Gvb0@b1GbWmULOtJo7QMX8LASp8PWvNr@H1KOXADBMy3h3HMsrhdUR60YGnE/zCBEObjhtd24k7N6lKzopg@qlI1chy5w6lz@yjUU57jITZnnqOGm/UsEP6fTbP7@DS977NSG8PuPz7sHfFe@xTMNLtvCJWUTOs39rBM8/ttVt@f0AndakPOup8pKM53B8WPImWmZNTIl2v/0TG/C2304vj2qM1xfA/W@ZMxTI2cQxB9Hj6RAAyCyfiOLNezh0nw5rHOLMt@w45SlnubcTE9A4I6L0p3/OPlsZr0KnAjynY6s70bIuH@62QEAUMSRjphcIriFAqqKvBO6IAGAYBlUOxgA/eW@ZlJTCASSBis1yetFsnNZzWzZi1Ig4g1kXQ6fFS2y3kyG7MTiTe8ayvndBo5WdPknNwOasSUGSj1wR5sBXXuwPU99uB4rkgngTNi29lYzii1@Z45uGk8KBk6QQ9SpLeBx7al3DDiO7/8eOES88@//62Xnh8NKBA58mIQ/iDAM89wRIfh9JDPm85@PB47eP6EY0BU7vONK@3FMYmnXuIO@bERRBFvTy@r6Z5/egYLL@eYG61hwYUKTX3AwUm40Dg2vZByrUgnXvbKiILQbDIKyNTrJcNYB58buJSdKWT73IBJhGBBEoWoVUXyivQopghs3@3zBGTrh@E12@5DTP7@N37SAY0eqhCWs@nZ0dvajASWisWOF1w3nADW2SBfaBSmIAoyGQLMCXDkFnSa8nqVuEOHHcGAJmrZAQROww8hXhxfEO2EyHh0jOcRttdXcsdvfv@uZXYa38jIoP/4s4FboIxv4g/avhWLRZKB2AvUq/VmE5pXrTIRczMxJQsPKdmZ3FKp@GoiCpaZuLIDhRE732R6R6fsQIGdGgUYP@PBYRDD@oBXlQ3NF00jp0x8b@QlRLtISAXP1ymwBEr8RJTgiTVujmOX3Ix8JUPUFc0lVsWEN84QH89jRo0fs92b8voum/GSdicsI70p6aVyg5GTu2rUm6wU0V6IJ3atj@1px4gzrrTbsx/M0gzYFkYA/tzAlXPyx5fznN40v36NwQWL4kK22S4oLu/c/PzV@cnF5fHl2wtg44JTKZ2G0chZmQhUgrEPsdEw9NkRKPAj8mj8tNl4xuyG8CwFVBSSc0gdPBIBC/VsaVhStoqamONF3sYsybLtXmNqPvoeSU0dOWfSTgUrx@tmrpgpADIP1uQE7GqGPCjOfIu5YuSIpAEEaUAQA18ivHzbRtjdVgbPGX6I78D0lIx1KEbqCmo7ENLKgVO8OQxHcisRi/8lzMfgR57GHKGewhyAhadmX5v49PjVz2/fnGzOvTZtCrMBstSQta9OTmYQ04Id7DMNx5PNTG/C9GQ6Mwxg94f8uMTxV6YtXp58oCb10TD7sLZxUbB9oRgXN0E7opNjPwZD2uuBZejeJmhYwKLyw47liYcoAQP0pZ8rElFA2LixeUIJhmMKOYf7iXfOMTg2crztkL9NjX/@5a/8YL@dQPnf03Ifyv/Jyx8NZNDmSTDHcckaZMu7V@ckBm/FCR85szWa0GGgQ/ICiBy9EXDwhjEEwTmyK3pX4yitd8BPEAIwEy0fGjs2H406yjBJxjXDQP8OKVxfZ1vFdAZyAFupQ9Jj/DLB7yzAPht7lb1dywAktZtsQHZ8N8DtSz6gqtZAhYQbb9z41HVJvV4nYuw6Pm3s2ZyRRs75WBY/LRHNAazAQ4EWgT7QZdUD2pppNyXnFCwVu@IqlC2ZdGzw8lwu4CgUVgAQFauDlB8ieKIwZRWeBNJZwozqbRbiQHwRhGSEfGJf22QDaTAQH1sVhQ3dXW1T4vHMmjbr62IQ3yPYBYLVxG2qQ0BD/muL5gRQ/g9ebrVN7Vtn25ciS9053vwgRLn/OQfSQo4ughC3rU8BV6KUjFLZsPbUtXUipkMBtrgqvsKQsA5gXbnU@xyO4@MXJ69@Oju/2PiggUHK98FkIjfrhbamF1udZUG@p/MZS388NS5e/3iaMXIdq7TpPlbbBr@P2AOTvecbwptTsYaNiSzzewdmp5faKUuQthCybDXWAF/w3auNWRV1vmh16s12IG1M/3Xb10aSnscPjKDUjtm3RjLZYmBeZdvcl@E1qMcjn1FoCUJ4X9Y/qMg2yfFrhVLT6NEbA4/XBX21fS7mlPodbFX@yQfnQTY92Im0JgcJapOs5nKFja3IdUT4jlC4xOROzyWzkeYzntmxL6acAIL6yHM5dMyMK8//2Oc9kAG8SlZJAyQimICz3OiW5QGwzJdbez2P7fo60W1KwbLlgo487TLDBxf96gwbjFAYJZB@xEPf69pOozUjyxPex4639Xjse4mC58ozHfMroEZRkQCr7lM8lq4fdNIzcJIdVRfYaff5BPh1Ho7JKqd9SbPSG0hryEvIrT3QAEp@mowArs8ebyhaeEr@GGrQGfgoZ0i0YBYlpUEf9Sowuz6ks543AC@hqEUwKD9Y1uqc3FELkIvKYEM5q36Pe5brjPlNZ/trHHNaju4FPTpT5Kms1jrIHaiXp@9vZFXc0AH2gUH6tUHv/pcG2dp3knQRLk/p1xdOFrDA5Ok5HzgR/P4Tv@yARMEDnT76Aw0CUBkF0B6BghBnAnRGajH7DLm4/GRszS78a3pseN9LnMhzPwRfmDNslpLYC3AIn9qknbT77QC9gn1r/M7QDXuu5PzGrQGOXG0quWHDKpTzhUIuyCu5AF3Z8@eYySxy4CmvdFEXZwCk5XzVBn6CZ23kAjvn1JVcr1HKsx7wWiioc@jwLTb0ec5ZGLnn4JiKUBNx7VBysYriMHXdWgB@KKGcURw547kiEnGGX97h9DmvUEAc9NwVIvDNaF8UmJlqXxgsd7LTAMkYjDI1vqMMv/4qWXsQqx/ulZXwsFTeyUtEOhKNfPvlhw8vbmy55fRL@i@d8@vz8z@pbUWWXpyJ1q5ok7whSEbe/LpvGJ8@fYLQgbSaelPvqC1N7rSU5v5@3i7uVfPFo6IlF22J@JZpWapSKqkX7d3AfgaXYp3LcqUsX3zET0cOd@CH/cK1fMX7DqtJqxnI5rWjEuWXmSA1n4HOlPd2jp4BSrTArlrtiAjSN0G6FaRP9U@CBJGQ1Gx2FotCvVWv683mrKl1mi1BmgvSbCFIJRFZkBekxqz@hg3RetnkYxV@AXb@DM@61mmNz38@Ob44KZbqmlQ6PX5RLF28/VGy4K2yesXGMr6@OTl@efb2sljivX7/6t3J23Oo9zxvHPd6cS8cdppHRwVd07QjvdkBfGY/FJqFRpIk5MNVXp/xa/ds7@xIkF42Z28NrQ6o/CxIb1gvrQ3ItVXo@1WQWlJLOSwdlkzfvDGta@v6dXi2@j07Q7UQ96tiGB4BiDczP4eROTSHVs@yrJlJ35q35u3MHIVnVg@KFH7MERQ9sz8zB2ZgBpZ1Z8iHf0dn4euzEIYKoVsyMxMc1ezDc3B29hoG68PEn@HHM01EdWbewK/pW@z6eGWqZrstQLrYqeyNS3u/tJjhqRx0WnTmJR2RFOV2S@7YkhG32wbXdLEEaorNi8XV1cvjy@OrKwPzp1k9VzgqaEdwNZqFevo4lHpNZKFe32kLsjJ9//49/r2f3kx5iRV43ftl4/oLK8B180DfuwXc5GxVOvOFSuDnWVu2ZY62olBwm4potWelPimJzBsdgC2wyhDxK3sVtdncq8D7XlXVFBNbd9WPVr2eNpXUMBLlmRhGMpkv@I8yX9QVdqn4o6pYmd6bqgLNagXeZnNlVlfqCtZBFfaaL5pYZHBzKLUUtaMuFrwO7opa52M2VSAL4/3/o98whuSUyNJCQvsfkN2KCtkEVXf3lGrhIP1p7AAxiliWy0CjKDtyq3WUL@f3d1uHnXwnr9Tzer7d7MzWL1WWCOhWpiINS0LuCZJuvxGtkiijyti4hxb6VPchui8f2LKSv39VrYNCvnDUyh8c8Mny@a87KvSGsUW4JNAqopB6s57tJyirrQW1CX9zkvKXqIs56EPaBg5ESffG2u2ZaTJ4u9vIzSVnYbPhyUJcgvPtcza8Itts01ScizknalkdcSHm5t0Fetm8pTL/WNm17fwuL@9XbTDrVj5tMaElLUIDjR2XrSaw5KhIMnBYBaIaXTrwAkEaCzZuIPLdSlETuTKT6gHrJMWxANFCFyQ5JfsmRIO@70Qk7Pd3eD2EPZAvUnD71Pcx8caofxpGfm8KkeiOIMUUrtG5QyeUTieTKV1eL7y45nz@DNHsGH0SBCumoOPcpdJBtVI9KJeqxepBdbdi7VUqRatUtPar@wdmEdxR1dqrVg6sYnX3oLy7u3sArZWDfUGiQc/rGwbYf0sUCStASIxfRdXx@7FQHzbBn/RoH/dan82UnvpM6i0rJlUilqttE6Jw/GIQBa3O0WApJIbYNewTxSxOYPVWDidVcW9frOXhKR6KZSgyAc4UYsogaVFui6LaOugcivsVsQZOUpOfW4dE3D8Qa@L@vqjaIh1URHGPlPZFewGYZhxY0kDApuk6gT9NE7CdhwGKuA@2RbYBzOZd/mWtT3RdixMnwpSJgUNGsXcgYjWA1LnmNivdfK1oacUjPiTZswRpIfTwq4zdAxt9KdiXelPIycgGuSxIWjncDaVcLgce@LIplsUzvW6kbrVpMJ/aRjeLrkzPvHRTiChu1/bwX4y4iaxWVBsrY6EB9YKN60uU0gV9iz6tzYesf5PYiTs5ny@38dJPkGuvASnFqV2wz81asOq@/dHz59Wy1mRxKcTHCwKhwGJ8cfBx/2P14@u3Z2/PTo9q1VoVFp0Uf1XDivUt@MmWamO5vCuXwfM2JI6gta9KzdK@Hju3Uic9GFJ291UCb2xJlSypP2XX0n1sOJO10pb36c2IRSSASfV3vcHAK/3u9aevkJrKMiFWbu@bVue/dbi9OOMiUsS9iqjCaow/Xn28kgSpQsRSRSSkYEBAZxh/KsGiOTjYq@5Jwq@G8VhqC63LyLxPIWidjLaF5seR99rBvcRgGZ5D4fUEcrjloiK4qjDpGTbv1rGVdqeK/Y8a1AmIF6qVggUnGrhFtsFJ8vh1Yaujknm2Oa5gK@7Pqsvt3Igmkyggps233XEIz14WYRZcp6SBAExlwNsqXsOyiVfHweAJAXw6A15Zj0IDi5g4Miy8jmoL6/vUDJMm9F7DZa1/ocDBFxwtTo876nGyedvyFdAb4Xmeq6S91XsALbMDMHLblFMyv4cMyNCU5QhF8pvJuNcfchU1o4mhsGpM61eiWAj5pDiyBSQ7P7aFPyiuOsccyv42ev7c/ThujTq2Omok@CwURvZCuFY8DpJPGqOGZtljQNZOWoWC12mM1D8oY4b8qGECMMyNI8fqfCnpoJGKK1aLX1qB9i3oFE9bQcHqFCfF/IfGl6LTMIsz@AO2Ff3iL8C8jJVK0vhSCGynDn@Yzt3hxLgRFxz77vEBdLlW/MaXltNpmKrtQ8dC4RSIATzjll8odFSY3IfGzY62//y5U/CbM9vXNBWhPpYPT1sJFDqFBr7XFKc@O/zSmkD/mgLPBkzjq4A89LsrAxgP8LOBx1x8K9Q5jjNEbwbojRqN/IfD/Id8Y2fnS2umjTpFzv6auRI8Ij9D5Nd1RMl/WFcsxhIWwyjiD17tBz0fE7EI2gdMLo7XenIM8x@gZbxaDYv/Bg)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)

### Explanation

#### Adding RunR

RunR is a 2D language with explicit entrypoint.

Spec clarifications:

- If there are several `S` last `S` is used as entrypoint
- `O` treats current number as ascii value and prints it as character (so it is equivalent to printf("%c"), not printf("%d"))
- arith operators pop value from stack

RunR program: `S9^7^8^MUOUOF`. `S` starts program, then we push 9, 7 and 8 to stack. When `M` (multiplication) is executed we have
current number 8 and 8 on top of the stack, so result is 64 as current number. Then we subtract (`U`) 7 from it and print it with `O`
(64-7 == 57 == '9'). Then subtract 9 and print '0'. `F` terminates the program.

The program contains `S`, so I added `p` before it to fix alphuck.

#### Underload

To fix Underload, we need to enclose RunR code in parens. But there were no place for parens on line 59, so I placed `(` on line 46 and 
`)` on line 60 after `#s|`.

#### gnuplot

Added `set print "-";` to gnuplot code on line 29. This makes it output to stdout instead of stderr. Fixed alphuck as usual.
Updated driver - as it turns out gnuplot is installed on TIO (as a tool, not as a language).

#### Incident

Added some detokenization at the end of C/C++ code. Prior to that I tried to add it on line 58, but broke Fission.

Answer (score 10):

## 93. [Set](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Set), 2720 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.xxxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp
set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof( "(\"           ); print'(''72'')';end!"           ); main( ){puts("92" );return 0;}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003381 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2808 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvLdts4luvwzB/0BiZVISmJL8myZb1sV2J3p7rS9sROMieS4lAUJDHmQ0VSlhxFOb2dObPofW9m2f/R2/6K/pGaewFSki3ZTp2ZOWdomwSJC@C@cB8A3LPj0a@/SniR89C7HXphQhIaJ6QfuTc00smPt@TIduNKqSwIDCoK@xPHDYYkGVHiBuNJQgauR2PBsRPSIuO0Fx0LRCIRtfscTBiEEcEmxL/2iEuc8Zj0PHukO8RzAfbUrAJ8HPoIk9BoHFG4xySgtE/iMXXcgeuwsQidJTSI3TCIdeI612Tqeh7pUw8arBBwitAZmcRrn/hwutAPBQKXM76H7vItRwEmoBnJdGxHjOSQjBn9GeXTyB6PAUlBIheAeOL6NCZuIseE2rGLfIQmMQ36jFvjJYdDYgfrVJIb1yY24DuJWN8xjRIgT2f9khGNKHRp4@DDyPaJMo3cBFiAzDwm59SOyGVEqQqjgBBo7NhjwOPOkDBYiCMkSIjOhNVoyCdnpzIIjbfQ7XEiSFH58l9/EmyiN0nuqg5/TVGsCyd/eknmuQ6WAQvoDAQ7jhRbJc1vJDY6HQp/M6tnDKOFAL0KwBWPGOE4MWxtDAhqCSBo2FjEknZT0sfe2sCkcU8Wa6rEofogDfIqIO@KjDJnEkUU8Fgx1b4Gor0wGAI/gdhoEiA/ArJnggicMOjHRUJvgGthwGUUThmHL0cuCC1Gkdg9YJDtIO/5NGAMhYkAupdyNBs3Dr0Jg4OWcYIKCFyBptjjqwF5Rwa262ETqMeuONYRjSdegm0mQR8l77sB7eskQ8MJ@wjkhzcwnA2dsg8wc/y1@caQAmAQRMhIxap//uWv/eEQ@jl2nDDqp@r6jvRDZ@IDwjZD1gZVRIUNA9tjaAFcEUfnzWGAG9tz@3aCwwe36RAMCTbqNJx4fRLCgNHUhak1sm9gOg4G1EkoV/JwkgCOReLb19xKuFxzgXDf7oFg2QBsbEa2Ro5egJQcylVG8yfJoEq08QmRY@OjclhTDnc6FHBTdTWfM4xhHfRNz7NP8CY/pjjvjlfyRO25dEOcR954NAGrATVBPAZ7EiEzHRvIidGsJGD5iqTHGM1sEag6m6RTKkeU9GBmZ4QxHeE6gO01nLlpDyuZZnB3VYz21zQMtBOULIk3zIQXTmFghhuaT9DpAAe3hzYMlaQEHXOC@Ijsy13SrgPQdOytR0lV67kgHdQDMDapMNZoBPByicNAb1x6a5PCt2@hF4cb6ZUkiTsAIfugt9EtcShOBpgVlFs6HGTCFCN2QY/CATG1UqXyhPCTyDjWPoD1@GI8KmMk/p6Yj8mATolnB8OJPQRFDgNoYjsOHSfpDAJK4gTmyH1DyD5qqVXX45GQO7o/NrNuqb1fGwOtD5deaqNtVHtglA@s1jyY5cSOhmwmkr4bwXzxbu@PDgA39wYXPyHIHQQ@iQ@gkLkmUDI6o84kgekGijwduc4IdBexC/iE5dbx/vDwaX10MDnaYDk0ImO1npcE3Vh@QjQe7EJDiW72A1Yfu2rd@cCEv/7h8Z7t2N/ScbhEESzU2lfdsHXQvZRp4M8vMJYA85c5bzazlgHGkp/A4J/QMUX0lwkIDPTZHQYIYgdLx79mGd04kMFVuLELXEcXjrp@@eoM/cF7yqMY4Dv3ZevGPISYBpqnLhorMiEI1BmFRAuInOKgiMyjfga0jDhyWEFbCyNEVQc@KcgvVpV19JlHZ/cdKmltwrEh5SJpi2K3CD7Mi0GFgonnwcskYFNMoeocdM2hcazDhAHe6hiPAHZigaqLu4DJKAqnhC7UurxtuN8okBeTnjv7fygRB/Hid6BqTQzs0/fIYQMwE4QopqzbgGC8exH6aOfJe0Yx4vtjBL5hAP5AGN8mI7B0mkNEuxmOKaB0x5LIgCeE54paZyGdLOufQzdQ5vLOzo5ck1tyEUqHUGpg6RBLBSgdspLGSginY4m1KLIS1rZZC/zWlRftrOeZ2kXRzjBu/eKOFbtdq5W7Rbttpc8SPlVwJuA7AFrDB/Qjq80mFlVVbE2BUL03EDj5lyCcnyHkIz@76IkHECCuUgdhOVhHEDkzyndtqbiqKfFo9cbwgX36@HZ7FCGud8UaQAB3HaKOrkpXpm5V7nQBGc9my4Ebj9jtDugGWps1rHXs9wbstgWgloYBEFNgloR8YaYMI5EwBM2fMjA/DEKOCvDLDWzjDXvo4D224XPXSN9Bpkdhzg@p0XMDLD8Bph1UGeSg13MfAgW@IOrZcwtYNOltYxuEZ6MNP07uMD6ZRIlH@@nzH3/ugwA2xTOyb2MI6K@XhSvgG4pKGzworbQpvrDbdsl@nniQ7j3Rh2NjEG97y8L2vmrkDQX1B8kGLMsDTD2gDSMcMHWb@g1Tw5v0afbc3inj4d1wgLcOXJ9JDp4Y2zDL80Dze8EMb49JT@SFdt/giahLV6LkTKczexgGt8aaV9Oj3nfgmMUbZJV5JqNJMuF3TDafEpo7xr/HJmMKaVbsnkWNMLZ77gMcRCT2HlJaPhfQTGsDz77mxSssbieVExO5Q8hss@dDYBDtQUA@th1qTNnjQfsRTOIxEyYrPdJf5PH7QyBu4IBnDVaFhwCBTI/dfovKMUVwYB4gqrjYo62xyL3HVM/u3aIrG/12/cEBh4UC0cB2NJ1CwSwTLVzlYqtlpfH44faOk7Y/ONjemq9AsQ6cENJm@pQ/Aqfi@ranlfprxQfta@b6V6Vt5se@sSEo8OwYFCRJ2UxvQCzs9pjSop9wJp4drUqPqOwKnSzlfihrW7UZu07oualmZi9bBggwzLsfEq26wRVFdls1xbfUZL6EqAcd77dH7WboJJgsPaA632GReJ6CmeCaLujhQ@xywin@PThhR@EN5fftLujLVqy@w@JoHlMGiLU3m/edpzQU14HYbbslvN6KVeJ4W7/XyOswjCBRjUlJNx8Vz1Y1jl0vjMkFuz/GC0jR45jftyvwOttcO9CcEZ9Wy/L2ZluRYh6NHLP7A8K1vWHo7VWHhg23BzVgEg3QsKfP7zVqS6NkWU8apWX4EgZW@nzQml/D71PKgQsgYL5djGOWxe2K8qAFSyP@hwmEMB8XvLYTd2pWl5oVxfRRlaqR48gZTe3bR6Ge8hwPsTnzHDVcrGeB8P9smN3Hh@l/n5Xa6Hb/8W7viPfao2Cm2X1DqKRkWr@xhWWa32@zBt6ETuhWG3LW@0xBcb47KH4UKTMlo0a@XHuP9vldaKMXx7dHbY7tuTDPn4xhauQcgujz8IkEYBhMxndkuZ49TII3T8yJF2HY/@2aurQ61adDoRq5oMljQ7Bc/w3b0FmusMbFdCcKvrlRuu8QLzf3pFeBE1G23pqtIBEJV4EnPoQtSRjphMEpil0oqKrAG6EbHAYAlkGx7RVc4eY7NzGBeCRhsO6AtNskN5/VzJq1IE0i1kTS7fJe2VrryWzM9kXe8KbtnN1t5mRNk3NyJ6gRU2ag1AOrtBXUvgM3cNmD47kinQS2zxbVsZxRWucr9xAs4HbNyA76kKi9DVy2OOaEEV9/5pscl5gF//1v/XQXa0iBSN@NQQWHAe68hj4dhdNDPm46@vF4bOMuGPYBuYHHl8@0F8cknrqJM@KbVxDLvD29rKY7D@lOMLycY4a2hgUXKlQNAAc74ULj2PRDyrUiHXjZKiMKAsSJH5Cp209GsQ6eP3Ao29nIVtsBkwjBgiQKUauK5BXpU0xU2Orf5wnI1gvDa7boiJj8/W98vwUqXVQhLGfDsw3AtREJTFiLbXI4TjgBrLNOvtAoTEEUZDKEuRPgyC3oNOXfVeKMbLYRBJqoZdsgOAzfCnlxfEG0EyLjBjbuitTdgZI7fvP7d22z2/xGfIP@488GLsQyvok/aPtWLBZJBlJfoF6tV5tQvaqViZibiSlZuFXKdgaXSsVnE1GwzMSVbWv4bJeV6R2dsm0NtncVYBSP25dBDPMDXlXWNZ80zZwy8VzfTYh2kZAK7vLDdLehxPdlCe6b4xI9NsnNyFcyQl3RHGJVTHjjDPFwV8hv/pitIZXX1/qMl7Q3YXnxTUkvlZuMnNxVs9FipYj2Q9w3bH/sTLtGnHGl05n9YJZmwLYwAvDnBs6ckz@9nOf0lvn1awyBgCgu5Dpbi8XpnZufvzo/ubg8vnx7AWxccCql0zDy7ZWJQCUYexChjUKPbcQCPyKXxk@bjWfMbgjPUkBFITmbNMAvErBQz5aGJWWrqIk5XuR1zJIs6@5VpuZj4JLU1JFzJu1UsHK8buaKmQIg82BOTsCuZsiD4sy3mCtGjkiaQJAGBDHwJcLLt22E3a1l8Jzhh/gOTE/JWIdipK6gtgMhrRw4xZvDcCS3ErH4X8J8DH7kacwR6inMAVh4avS1gU@PX/389s3J5thrw6YwGyBLDVk7@3Iyg8ga7OCAaTjur2Z6E6b745lhALs/4ps2trcybfFy/wU1aYCG2YO5jZOCrU7FOLkJ2hGdHHsxGNJ@HyxD7zZBwwIWlW@5LPddRAkYoC/9XJGIAsLGzc19UjAcU4hBnE@8cY7BsZ7jbUcNOtT451/@yo8XdBIo/3taHkD5P3n5o4EM2tyP5jguWYNseffqnMTgrTjhvj1bowkdBjokN4D41fWBgzeMIQjOkV3Ru@pHab8DfoIQgJlo@dDYsfFo1FVGSTKuGQb6d0gkBzpbsKYzkAPYSh1SL@OXCZ72APts7FX2di0DkNRusg7ZJuIQF1F5h6paAxUSbtxx81PPIY1Gg4ixY3u0uVfnjDRy9sey@GmJaA5gBR4KtAm0gSarFlDXSpspObtgqdgUZ6FsyaRbBy/P5QKOQmEFAFHxc5DyQwRPFKaswv1IOkuYUb3NQhyIL4KQ@MgnduYn60iDjnjfqihs6O5qsRQ3ida0WV8Xg/gewS4QrCZuUx0CGvJfWzQngPJ/8HK7Y2rfutvOqyx153jzWIpy/1AJ0kKOLoIQF89PAVeilIxS2bD21LV5IqZdAbY4K75ClzAPYF451P0cjuPjFyevfjo7v9g4VsEg5ftgMpFbjUJH04vt7rIg39P5jKU/nhoXr388zRi5jlVadR@rbZ3fR@yBwd7zZenNoVjFxkCW@b0dsz1U7ZSlaVsIWdYaa4Av@BraxqiKOl@0u41WJ5A2hv@67cyTpOfxmBOUOjE78SSTLQbmVbbYfhleg3o8cphDSxDC/bJ@rCNbqsczE6WW0ac3Bm7yC/pqEV/MKY072Kr84AnnQTY82In0Sw7S5BZZjeUIGwui64jwDDFcYnKn5ZLZSPMZz@zYuS07gKA@ch0OHTPjyvM/dsgIMoBXySppgEQElwFYbnTL8gCY5ssFxr7L1p7t6DalYFlzQX1Xu8zwwUm/2kkHIxRGCaQf8chze3W72Z6R5T7zY5vsejz23ETB3e2ZjvkVUKOoSIDV8ChujjcOuulOPMk2zAtsz/18Avw6D8dkldO@pFnpDaQ15CVk@C5oACU/TXyAG7DHG4oWnpI/hRo0Bj7KGRJtGEVJadD9fgVG10d01neH4CUUtQgG5QfLWu3W22oBclEZbChn1e9x5XSdMb/phMEax@y2rbtBn84UeSqrtS5yB77L0/c3sipu6AA75pCeeejfP@@QzX07SSfh8qzA@sTJAhYYPN1tBCeCp1DxfAkkCi7o9NEfaRCAyiiAtg8KQuwJ0BmpxewwdHF5cG3NLvwh3by87yVO5LkXgi/MGXWWktQX4BA@dUgn6Qw6AXqF@q3xO0M36nMl5zVvDXDkakvJjZpWoZwvFHJBXskF6MqeP8dMZpEDT3mli7o4AyAt56l14Cd41mYuqOfshpLrN0t51gJeCwV1Dg2@xYY@z9kLI/ccHFMRvkRcO5RcrKI4TF23FoAfSihnFH17PFdEIs7w/B8On3MLBcRBz10hAt@MzkWBmanOhcFyp3oaIBlDP1PjO8rw66@StQex@uFeWQkPS@WdvESkI9HId15@@PDipi637UFJ/6V7fn1@/m9qR5GlF2eitSvWSd4QJCNvft03jE@fPkHoQNotvaV31bYmd9tKa38/Xy/uVfPFo6IlF@sS8SzTslSlVFIvOrtB/RlcinUuy5WyfPERD7Ac7sAP@4Vr@Yr3HfYl/cxANq8dlSi/zASp9Qx0pry3c/QMUKIFdtVqR0SQvgnSrSB9anwSJIiEpFaru1gUGu1GQ2@1Zi2t22oL0lyQZgtBKonIgrwgNWeNN6yL9ssW76vwC7DzZ3g2tG57fP7zyfHFSbHU0KTS6fGLYuni7Y@SBW@V1StWlvH1zcnxy7O3l8USb/X7V@9O3p7Dd9d1x3G/H/fDUbd1dFTQNU070ltdwGf2Q6FVaCZJQj5c5fUZv3bP9s6OBOlla/bW0BqAys@C9Ia10jqAXEeFtl8FqS21lcPSYcn0zBvTurauX4dnq9@zM1QLcb8qhuERgLgz83MYmSNzZPUty5qZ9K15a97OTD88s/pQpPBj@lB0zcHMHJqBGVjWnS4f/vXPwtdnIXQVQrNkZibYqzmA5/Ds7DV0NoCBP8OPa5qI6sy8gV/Ts9j18cpUzU5HgHSxW9kbl/Z@aTPDUznotunMTboiKcqdttytS0bc6Rhc08USqClWLxZXVy@PL4@vrgzMn2aNXOGooB3B1WwVGunjUOq3kIV6Y6cjyMr0/fv3@Pd@ejPlJVZ4PyXv02u6vK0930/hunmg8d0CrnK2K935QoW08VlHrsscbUWh4DYV0erMSgNSEpk3OgBbYJUh4lf2KmqrtVeB972qqikm1u6qH61GI60qqWEkyjMxjGQyX/AfZb5oKOxS8UdV8WN6b6kKVKsVeJvNlVlDaSj4DT5hq/mihUUGN4dSW1G76mLBv8FdURu8z5YKVGG8/3/0G8aQnBJZWkho/wOyW1Ehm6Dq7p5SLRykP80dIEYRy3IZaBRlW263j/Ll/P5u@7Cb7@aVRl7Pd1rd2fqlyhIB3cpUpGlJyD1B0utvRKskyqgydVxDCz2qexDdlw/qspK/f1Wtg0K@cNTOHxzwwfL5rzsqtIa@Rbgk0CqikEarka0nKKulBbUFf3OS8hfKizkoBK8DB6Kka2Odzsw0GXy918zNJXtRZ92ThZhB854V1r0i19miqTgXc3bUtrriQszNewv0snlLZf6xsluv53d5eb9aB7Nu5dMaE2rSIlTQ2HbYbAJLjookA4dVIKrZo0M3EKSxUMcFRL5aKWoiV2ZSPWCNpDgWIFrogSSnZN@EaNDz7IiEg8EO/w5hD@SLFNw@9TxMvDHqn4aR159CJLojSDGFyz@36YTS6WQypcvrhRvX7M@fIZpll4Bo7JDKflawhNeYgh5YfEHexc9QgrT@D4CMP3FGuMvhJujQINIxBR0RL5UOqpXqQblULVYPqrsVa69SKVqlorVf3T8wi@DLqtZetXJgFau7B@Xd3d0DqK0c7AsSDfruwDDAeViiSFgB4mk82NXAI3ChPmqBM@rTgRvQZ2Sm9NVnUj/7QCZVIparHRNCeDz0CGJUyRytnUJiCHwBccUsTmDqVw4nVXFvX6zl4SkeimUoMunPFGLKoCai3BFFtX3QPRT3K2INPKwmP7cOibh/INbE/X1RrYt0WBHFPVLaF@sLwDTjwJIGAgZR1wn8aZqA9eMmx0IhotIR13ROTf8HSVZkeb8ky6pch0527oEgSUARJ0g8KInwMaLJJAqIWV/w0f9lbfjouhYndoSpG@sdMpu9AxE/A0iDz6BWpZevFS2teCRwnduzBGkh9PGMyu5BHX062LlGS8jJOLxcFiStHO6GUi6Xg0jgsiWWxTO9YaTuvWUw395Bd48uVc@ihZYQUVw27uM/XHFTXa0g@kMSC034LtRxnotSalhu0bd2eJeNbxI7f0DO58vlxPRAdu018sSuXbDDd@0uUb/9yfXm1bLWYvExxOkLAqxZjC8OPu5/rH58/fbs7dnpUa1aq8Lkl@KvalixvgU/1aXaWC7vymWIAJoSR9DaV6VWaV@P7Vupm25QKbv7KoE3NrVLljRAn7V0WZsuba205X1647PACBCp/q4/HLql373@9BUyZFkmxMrtfdMa/LcBtxdnXEKKuFcRVTAK8cerj1eSIFWIWKqArhQMiCsN499KMP0ODvaqe5Lwq2E8lmFD7TJBGFCInSf@tgzhOHJf27ikGSyzBCi8nkAquZyeBOcn5l6j1t1vbM7e@cT@YQ@@CYgXU2os2NHQKbJ1VpLHo5btLszdbI1ewVpcJlaXq8pLzeer/9iFW18WYRSca6SJAExjwOkrbtOqE7eBncET8oh0BLyyFoUmFjF/ZVi4XbUurC@XM0xa0HoNl7X2hQIHX3C0OD2O3@dk87rlK6Dn47aio6St1XsAbbMLMHLHlFMyv4cMSBSVZQ9F8pvJuNceUiY1o4mhsKpMv69EsRDySdGvC0h2flwX/qg46hxTufo3//lz5@O47Xfrqt9M8Fko@GC2rhWXg@STpt/UrPoYkK0n7ULB7TZ99Y/KmCHvN9HGwdjYc6zOl5IOmqm4YrX4pR1o34Ju8bQdFKxucVLMf2h@KdpNsziDP2Bb0Sv@AszLWKkkzS@FoG434A@zyjucAGtdsOt3dzGgybXiNb@07W7TVOseNCwUToEYwDNue4VCV4XBPajcbFj3nj@3C15rVvc0TUWoj@XD03YChW6hie81xW7MDr@0J9C@psCzCcN4KiAP7e7KAPoD/OrAYy6@FeocxxmiNwP0/GYz/@Ew/yHf3Nn50p5pfrfI2V8zV4JH5GeI/LqOKPkP64rFWMJCKUX8wa39oOdjIhZB@4DJxfFaS45h/gPUjFezYfHf)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)

## Explanation

Set is pretty simple.  Here is the program

```
set ! 57
set ! 51
```

This prints ASCII 57 and 51, which is 93.

I added this inside of the Cood program because that seemed like the most appropriate place.

### Alphuck

Since I added two new `s`s I had to balance them with `p`s in Alphuck.  I added two `p`s to the end of the evil line and everything was just peachy.

### Incident

Incident tokenized `set`  So I added a `et` to the Cood to break the new token.

Answer (score 9):

## 22. Underload (`stringie`), 174 bytes

```
#v`16/"<"6/b.q@"(::):: :(22)S#;n4"14"
#>3N6@15o|> ^*ttt*~++ %
#=~nJ<R"12";
#[

print((1/2and 9 or 13)-(0and+4)^1<<65>>62)#46(89999+++++!)=#print(17)#]#echo 21
#8dggi2` |1|6
```

As before, there's a literal ESC character immediately after each of the 8 and 2 on the last line.

This program prints [**22** in Underload](https://tio.run/nexus/underload#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**21** in Nim](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**20** in Prelude](https://tio.run/nexus/prelude#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), **19** in Reng (testable [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)), [**18** in Cardinal](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**17** in Julia](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**16** in Pyth](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**15** in Haystack](https://tio.run/nexus/haystack#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**14** in Turtlèd](https://tio.run/nexus/turtled#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**13** in Ruby](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**12** in Fission](https://tio.run/nexus/fission#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**11** in Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**10** in Befunge-93](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**9** in Perl](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**8** in Retina](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**7** in Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=I3ZgMTYvIjwiNi9iLnFAIig6Oik6OiA6KDIyKVMjO240IjE0IgojPjNONkAxNW98PiBeKnR0dCp+KysgJQojPX5uSjxSIjEyIjsKI1sKCnByaW50KCgxLzJhbmQgOSBvciAxMyktKDBhbmQrNCleMTw8NjU+PjYyKSM0Nig4OTk5OSsrKysrISk9I3ByaW50KDE3KSNdI2VjaG8gMjEKIzgbZGdnaTIbYCB8MXw2&input=), [**6** in SMBF](https://tio.run/nexus/smbf#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**5** in Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**4** in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**3** in Minkolang](https://tio.run/nexus/minkolang#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), [**2** in Vim/V](https://tio.run/nexus/v#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag), and [**1** in Python 3](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JcuxDoIwFEDRvb/AUvti0kIUX4EKpTTODg46GgkqBllACXEi/DpiPNsd7gSfApXPDFP@bf3eMa610JpqLqU4QdqEDENGwAYHtcOoHSzN3b7v3dHz6JJANjZ7c2QoWUrgTMirq5uec/TltSlpQtuOYiBWfDOnF4ocjVGRtUoKCBWPk5n3sxAZ/F/cCrjA4/5sqUQCsVNWVS2dgg44qGn6Ag).

`stringie` is the Underload interpreter used by Try It Online! Fortunately for polyglotting, it ignores non-command characters rather than crashing on them, so the main thing to ensure is that there are enough stack elements that we don't get an empty stack crash (done here with `(::):::`; the code probably doesn't actually need that many colons, but I added them anyway as padding to remove awkward vertical alignments). Because it had to appear fairly early (it needs to be before any instances of `aS^:*~!`), I placed the Underload code on the first line; thanks for Sp3000 for suggesting a place where it would fit safely.

I needed to leave an additional space on the first line because Cardinal doesn't like `:` lined up with `%`; I also needed to structure the Underload code to avoid parentheses lining up with each other vertically (which Prelude dislikes). Pyth was the hardest language to get working, and I needed to resort to advice from Sp3000 there (who suggested moving the double quotes around; this combination works). In an earlier version of the code, the Underload was further to the right, but that got in the way of Turtlèd.

The space immediately after the Underload (i.e. after the `S` of `(22)S` should still be safe; the Underload doesn't change that. In order to avoid causing problems for Underload, ensure that your code has matched parentheses, avoids `S`, and isn't intelligible enough as Underload code to cause problems in its own right. `(::)` has a tendency to breed once it's placed on the stack (I intentionally wanted to write the Underload in a fairly robust way to make continuing the chain easier), so most random sequences of non-`S` characters will be safe from here, but it's possible to defeat the "ignore the rest of the program" if you try hard enough. If you need an `S` for some reason, try ensuring that some pair of parentheses captures it; that'll cause Underload to treat it as data rather than code and avoid producing stray output.

Comment: Any hints on where 1 or 2 characters (other than spaces) can be added later in the program? I'm trying to do a hexagony submission, so it's ok if it has to be certain characters, as long as it isn't just white space. The addition of all the `:`s means that I have to route program flow around them so they don't cause divide by 0s

Comment: @MistahFiggins: How late do you need them? Immediately after `print(17)#` is a location that every language with block comments, and every 2D language, currently ignores, so as long as you add characters that are safe for the languages which parse everything, you should be OK. Digits should hopefully be a pretty harmless thing to use if you just want some sort of padding and don't care what it is.

Comment: This will work, thanks! There are 22 languages now, so it's a little hard to keep track of what's run in which language.

Answer (score 9):

## 42. [evil](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil), 930 bytes

```
#  4"16" 3//v\(@#/;\D"14"<;n4
#/*`3 afaaZ">;[77*,68*,@;'1,'1,q)(22)S#   ␉␉␉␉ (
#yy␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=␉x
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#␉<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][<<<]>+.---.>][
#px%>~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.R␉>]|
#[#yy#yy0l0vx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100(^_)
#|␉
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13   ) )-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"␉*
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#mmeeaeueewuuw*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<␉>//
#
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  a>>>
#>27.say# /7Jn~15o|  
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17) ###^_^_LEintnd"3"z!]/*///@!32*<>Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVlJd9tIkj4Lf6EuaZA2AZLYSFteQNCSbbmeq1xVHsv2zDNJSyCQJGFhYWERKcnSm@vMm0Pf@zLH/h997V/Rf6T6iwQ3SVRVFywCiczIiMjYA/6tQhd7l4Rn4zDJWc6znPlpcMpTnb04Y3tukD1qtSVJQKWJX3hBPGb5hLMgnhY5GwUhzyTPzVmXTRdYdBqwCku565dg0ihJGW1h0UnIAuZNp2wYuhPdA1iWRLSU83SactwzFnPus2zKvWAUeIIE4/Ocx1mQxJnOAu@EzYIwZD4PsWFN12sCGSuyjamSii75icRwedMbXK7eqhwwMV@elE/dVJw0YVNx7OWBZ6k7nYJJqcIOwXgeRDxjQV7LGHezgMSHLRmPfSGk6UqwCXPjzVOy08BlLvgtUoE742mO4@kCL5vwlAOlS8THqRsxZZYGOURAMtxn77ibsg8p5yqoQPY889wp@LhGEsQSopDTQXSho06ndvDL6xp0Ve7Q3WkuVdL2h//4QXKZ7rDqkY2fI8u2dPDzK3ZR7dMYXAAZ9DlNFVdlzhXLjH6f4ze3hsY4vZSAVYJUQmYk09wAZjfNwd56pJ229Gm4QZZ1bmhiw35KKB@6YG9i9qkpzuUVacrBxVqk7gmOHCbxGNLEUdMiJmnEbNeEArwk9rMm46eQWRKXGkpmQr4fJgFUlpFC3CHE43ok@dL2hThh/bC8hTyXdLMkLAQcdmY5mR9kgq2E8c2IfWIjNwhpC9YJVcl1yrMizGlPEfuk9yiIua@zJRte4hNQlJyCnAukYgLuEm04mWAKwFBDIo5KS//8y1/98Rh49j0vSf2FsX5ifuIVERh2BbMuDJHMNYndULAFuCZRL7eDwKkbBr6bE/n4bEFCMCGozpIi9FkCguksgGNN3FM442jEvZyXJp4UOXhsssg9KUNDUNotDh65QyhWEBC0xbE1tvcSWvJ4aTBaVOSjJ0ybHrBaZnxRnj9Tnt/rc/Cm6mq9ahhjG9am18UU3mq/Zzif9tf6lMh89tmIz1joxuPCHeOISYwNrufxab6QLWSU5ZDeTQcRk9rC2/VsIlX3blIWVr@IAxs0yC5LT1z4rksC8ZIogjK0EPpnbjoWOmJ@kEKS4dlN6gA4vUFcPiaQawwcy3ewsAxZsHA@516RQxG8yWaTwJuwmeAuLlVZ@s1N8pjapA5j1EYr0sSM1X3QknRjNUVs3IlCI0XfxoN4QKi61yaETWxOlAdETD6kfAAjXgZgcpJ1klidHcL4gcJLyn8tIFz4ajCOCcSNV8F7w76DLK7B4YMsgIQoDAdY@fDmF/Lq/@RlJoKMyoi06ZIJ8hK2L8IsLSwFJnFvkjAtZrUFD4osouJXsGVkqScG2kYqkFUd0lJIamJpiehrmVhvhkXWvQ0nSNaarCfLgyYiUZhB3XERhngpYuEPClcvYBcezzIdxg231SmngDu5wdXL64D5JE1mjF@qdm0bOaGQDzjzW0Rf9jZA4ExGiNXrHC4y/pyyVV@Sp2f5JInb141XXq@0yrTxyYhcOOL0bLtDy5uoxIafgvgkIc0b0XJ0ZOrWo2soUHHc3jkKsom4XQO9xdbtFbE7i4YjcdsCEJNp3ZCXWIiSOCmJQ0JB7BrvxUOHg27j4LofXCP/gkNVY649bRvDIDaGfHQX5OsXL94ImNFwGNwFBDFQYbV8bgFLi@E2KQ3dbHIrTrJrcv5QpHmo@UZOT/6P//Yh79vamLhnGVLpyWpwFPMZaUYb3amcxVZ6EbftivxahCiz/gCH51L6dMPVYDuuZ@w9h7UjvcWiugKnYQh3hMgQMG6bMzwhLHy@fG5HKmR4PdyWu@Mg0mDLu7opFIhXSiFTqoXvwHIjZ5RoqOpIw8T1jbIODPhao6Xs@dwdJ/GZsRGQ9HT4b7C6DOtsXfjlkyIvyjtVe3@ku2BKv99zwQWk@Wj/hXWweNwBDyZ277Ld0m1SRBftdeieGEMaHo0w3H7U8jBpMEZpuXzeBcYzEXi0YZKcaGU5nxnItCh4pq7HhfbWr1vt6idk6xAV/eHPHw/f/a6BCYrAloblfSu6N7GHLBbnf4wJYgjF7c9YpjAUzw1hnu3SOKkh0zbkGNyQfOgOz6iDmPx5IyOq40aDacm68F/3e9Pp3Zs8b/umsiMU@7wEhSz/o7SE3BJEOG7L3xjeaTRBoiFhxRl5apqVljYqIKAtwck9dZnmhW4G08gX0uWn0Ia43dogsu570eWsiku0OGVzhrkgXRTj2arfraxXWeyiRkSapvGyXLLLej2biDIfZbmP@PIxDkSBhLairE6bbIiSR8Tyv//NX3Q/Y55nLAoyVPfjmPp1lKCTZPa8pLugvo82GoUXoYC9hmUFpb3cZ9ksyL1J2fOg0vj4@sMTqqmGfPnVAC/vKK5sMFEeG0sjsICORVTQJTN@wktbX9Bd7VqeyUP3FsVsFvj5JNPZYYAGBNJKV6U4OEkJLM7ThHylyd4wn5MjiQLwa4EaJ4SLi7KTOPn735jnZqKCBjJwjfGSvOgbNygyeIIlvgGgVyvA9RLJOU@TBYhCMkalU0AiZ/BUXs6rzJu4VAHRFxlt2ToRmbJ9erl/yDT0TvTVgzopOxgp1f3333/qmQM06pGBrGtQ5SfkJt/XHluZ3GRLEPuSo1bcXDaxvF6tMbk6lxfHog5bNJQrmyrtjSk0Fupa9jyRaM6F2fGZ6HkgWvTiVMhR14tCO8vxqgrUCtJ0hFpaO8zZI/okxCEKjMo2ntFHFlASoKw6Z9/YhIxE85j1yMRbKYmQWsjIWVdHmwWp8YoPCxHGT1t6q@2Ic1SPnE5XjFLuJ9Rn9r70/YGRLcXR78/vm605yeuBQd5y8POri6reNb99y9wzWb6sqRtfjQ7m8HwYA3XvovuW6EsSiSop8msdIYx/UvYuaGhW@s1WfQixNCLrDHFO6qpF7sjooIyEqbP9MIM1@T7ENDzLSbowq7L1WPUfcoXF@srVm0yWbn3@or2ZMNjFJxH06WkqeJigDisdH4oR/jUTHwRgl/BoXdelmUcqECi29fJ9bvzzL38t@/d@jvH/LMYjjP@vHH8xSKXGraa@PMgt@W3k0eBaGFycfAsXDMT@fwsTMcb/W457fVO7Gmz7tnCDDSK4Sq4fkhMeZ7/TOWs5QQTnmz10sNi90UMvp@BoSucadbVs79c6lauWDBprvJ50qyjbJLpMgisSmztvH21pnRDtoipEYqDPdYB6CQ8J8mds70cex/yMKXCRyE3PmFsgVaZqc/mpuLn6vHNbIwe1izBB5VA1bOF69iWEf9xn/bw/6sekAfvM@M7QDftCqYbOmWEYntpVqhPHarTrjUY1rivVWLNU9cED8tjLauZUj3RZl@cA0qqhasP3lKrrVGO76naUqu@06mIHXhsN9QIbrjJDv6i6l0b1AYygiZmUn8L5uFLNVIrLpq5bl@DvaxLEVaMZudMLRWbynD4WEvlq0GgQD3r1iBi4MvqHDXAOmzo0RJywF3ZtjCNbRJLaDav67bcKYw9la1dmbcM47St7FcPuv5Kth3LHjh9KFaN@3GbuyHU/y1279/hxvbn7pN7cs2tWE3@/qkqrpR4CB9vBxRSpcna2Y7d37@1JlePOMduRKs7OXKp0Bo1OT@9qg25Pqux0KEjN3zfo6r3qNsrrLX4dbdDrdDqDbkPXNE3vDgA@nd/vXl1dNXYaV/U8z@s68L3qzj8aWod2qVLlvYDW9Pc73cE3qdIDE/gzQ/N0blon1glGwdz8Ojcn5sTyLct6Z/KP5nBuDs3E8nHn@GfOMQzM0dwcm7EZW9bcTDDw5qaHwQj3MS2NgOQr/gWmSbiJxKkZWuIyTeXLEfj5tiMJaSsKP3VDRbb689aoJasIpspTFXZhtSExlamaYlKAfah@sTodZfeR2u0quy0VIDWlf4G/S5VuPUUdqJcYlH9qrfJwV3nSeLr459xTK0T@m2M4ltF66Mydp71OtbHX0PZwOd1GZ/F4XhGC1QeGdHT0av/D/tGRY1UMQ6rofV22WvJOnVRji7SYhFwPkzFj7aeSjIvgnCEfB/EO7Ygizl1ecD4rilkdEz4fISHsnDOWwbFR3tW8mmY9l9tP5Gdy@7EsVeD91H92qFNP9ElXIn@nLy2KChslHIp6XDnu1@rGBRWPyrlqXxr12vGxVK0RXE1Q1trJw6RSrValTlduy7/onZ0uzUsO/WcHygO8EL@C44o5qIiQ1cJBlX7v9f7LptXRKi0xOPz4okJvj9avLby26fXtwfcH7w8O/qtpvXt7sH948P2bTwcf35Vj8Ot2u12p0m091pGAK8x4/EN8ZT1KvqH0qjz5zh@Pg9Z3xzvfrG@7VcOo1VqPGHMqpVlYj1UGMX85@nL09gATsY9jnN8bQASGsXev3ap3up9brdbTp0/l1u5vhvF7UR@rq5CIHiLNimhbTNxPg59cytjxKi5i8FOBELxSDCPNhMGQVHNtrtTW5pT4nxzMrVVIA5SwXlOUEaxOHwF6A5VdiGIpGDGFVpHXrLLSogsFUZHGzLSlEog6RXs1BBWyJOYQAE1STFQCx7JZ0CFkeCKULijQtdzRcGgY8lgRXAQD1V7BrDjpYvcGLxv7G40S/LJkqzyPF/nlscu11SvYi6h18JTFbvUGAKpXwNT6Zm1xzH/nGMjlygpDk/3pY9zYj6yhLs8kWFgvLubXqriU6nkzsiU6dn1qSz8qnnpB2cy@ih488L5Me9HAViMnp2ejEdmX0okSlCD13IkczbKnYNbOe41GMHAi9UdlKpiPHBPAoE2YM/VipenYWagrU5vnvVi7igfN1724YQ2aRbP@2Tlvuo7ZnOMHsTXD5q8Q3lKUSu6cN2Lb7eBHifWaJKZO1nDta1O05UQJnfOeO3BM1Q6xsdF4jcOAz6wXNhoDFcRDLN7eaIcPHriNsDu3Q01TCepL@/nrXo7BoOHQ@zPF7cyfn/cK7H@m4OmATKiCeey7rgPgA382ZFyqb816yeOc2JuDvchx6p@f1z/XnXv3zntzLRo0S/E/M9eKJ@bnxPymjSj1z5uGJUQiOgpFvh88u6/XMyY3YX0QcnO6sbPksP4ZK9O1N1z@Cw)

VIP Score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): 0.01255 (snippet in answer 40 checks this for all answers)

### Rundown

This program prints **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balances as described in previous answers.

### Explanation

I looked at adding evil based on @Chance's recommendation. It slipped in quite easily and broke less things that any of my other additions did. All of evil's commands are lowercase letters. The most useful ones to note are the mark/jump related commands. There are two mark commands (`m` and `j`), two jump commands (`f` (forwards) and `b` (backwards)) and a mode toggle (`x`) to switch between standard and alternate marking (whether `m`'s or `j`'s are considered, respectively).

The `f` in line 2 jumps the bulk of the evil code: `mmeeaeueewuuw`, which is a slight tweak of the [formula](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Evil#Constructing_Constants) for generating 52 from 0 pulled off of the wiki (the accumulator is already 1 when we finish the jump, so the `za` wasn't needed). The extra `m` was to avoid creating a new token in Incident.

#### Working with evil moving forward

evil shouldn't be very hard to keep happy. As long as you don't create an infinite loop or add any `w`s, you have nothing to worry about. If you need a `w`, you'll need an `f` before it and an `m` or a `j` after it (depending on the mode when the `f` is reached).

### Fixing things

#### A minor Incident

Incident was using `0m` as a token, which threw evil into an endless loop. I changed that token to `0v`.

#### Other stuff

**Hexagony**'s code needed to be oriented the other direction to avoid bloating the byte count with padding, so a `<` mirror replaced the `/`. This required a matching `>` to keep **perl6** happy.

For whatever reason, **Japt** did not like the new placement of Hexagony's `}`, so instead of "moving the MP to the right neighbor" I used a `*` to set the current edge to the product of the left/right neighbors. Since one of those is a zero, it gives us the zero at the current edge (which is all we really needed for Hexagony). Hexagony has a [handful of other ways](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony#Memory_manipulation) to direct the MP that also may have worked, so look into those if the asterisk becomes an issue.

And that's it. It's a little disconcerting how easy it was for evil to sneak into this polyglot.

Comment: I just realize I accidentally left that `f` in line 2 from my evil attempt. Oops. It looks like your code placement avoided all the problems I saw with mine though. Well done!

Answer (score 9):

## 45. [PicoLisp](http://picolisp.com/wiki/?home), 942 bytes

```
#  5"16" 3//v\(@;# # \D'[af2.q]'# "14"<;n4
#/*`3 gkggZ">[77*,;68* ,@;'1,q)  ␉␉␉␉(22)PSPP( 
#yx␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{#z}# (prin 45 ) (bye)<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++ndL+++<-][PLEASE,2<-#2PLEASE,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2DOGIVEUP]>+.---.>][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.>]|
#[yxyx0l0v01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1(d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100(^_))46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)a
#|
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"__*
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeecisajjapppp/*/
#define␉z sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(   )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<>//
=end #//
"""#"#//
#>27.say# /7Jn~49c53c'43'p;|
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#s!]#echo 21#^_^_@!32*<*///>ssZ222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVlJd9tIkj4X/kJd0iDLBEgC4GLJCwjaclnu5ypXlcaS3e@ZpCUQTJKwsBmLREmW3lxn3hz63pc59v/o6/yK/iM1X2SCizZXFyQBCWRsGREZS@r3Cl1sLw7OZkGcs5xnOZuk/glPTfbyjL1w/Wyr01UUAZXGk8LzoxnL55z5UVLkbOoHPFM8N2d9lpRUTBqwCku5O5FgyjROGaGw8DhgPvOShI0Dd256AMvikKZyniYpxz1jEecTliXc86e@J1gwvsh5lPlxlJnM947ZqR8EbMIDIKz5ek0QY0W28UlyMZVJrDBcXnJDytVblQMm4suV8sRNxUpjlohlLxd8mrpJAiGVCtuH4Lkf8oz5eS1j3M18Uh9QMh5NhJKSlWJj5kabq2QnvstcyFukgnbG0xzLMwVdNucpB0mXmM9SN2TaaernUAHpcIftcTdlBynnOrhA9zzz3ARyXGMJZjFxyGkhprBRr1fb/e11DbaSGKab5Eol7R78x0@Ky0yHVQ9t/Dmqaiu7v75iF9UhjSEFiMGeSaq5OnOuWGYNhxx/i/bYmqWXCqgq0ErArDjJLVB20xzirUfGScdMgg22rHfDEhv@I6EmsAV7E7EPTbEur0hTDinWKnWPseQgjmbQJpaaFhFpI2LbLRjAi6NJ1mT8BDqLI2mh@FTo92Duw2QZGcQdQz2uR5qXvi/UCe@H55X6XPLN4qAQcMDMcnI/6ASoRPHNlH1gU9cPCAXzREpKnfKsCHLCKaIJ2T30Iz4x2VIML54QUBifgJ0LouIDtku4scmEUACGGWKxVJr619/@PpnNQGfH8@J0UjrrBzaJvSKEwK4Q1oUjkrvGkRsIsQDXJO4SHQxO3MCfuDmxj85KFkIIwfU0LoIJi8EwPfWxsebuCTbjdMq9nEsXj4scMjZZ6B7L0OBLv8XCQ3cMwwoGgrdYtsFe/AgreVw6jBEW@fQJM5JdVsusT9rzZ9rzB0MO2XRTr1cta2bD28y6@IS32rcc58PO2p7kPQd@TLsoSOYFYgZmoixBNElJmZ6L5WQUVHKEuyYbC0WLSARHF1v0lNdSzsbY18uFCR@RPkD4Bu3bksLapku46y7GJxseBu@Ek@XZrSARxKdgLGSjmAmfjoi5O3PBKi8XtCMXJDmKL9eXdhzB04namLMnxtiHdcgPEGpKY2ysEeDdjoQBNWm9jU0Rumeg4skQvbYk86cwcgi/Tc@Yx2kzYFdwGeeISSEcI/PhR/GUtYzO1tYfGD9PrR3jo@Ua59Y3bUyLv2HmHTblpyxwo1nhzuDIcQQU1/N4kpc7CCvJcuyRm2FQfDTKmG5mc6X64iZvEdvKaL/Bg6KPtF4ZoV1yeygqhKqNALucuelM7EQ28VPsl@DsJncAnNxgrh4RyDUBjtR7RFgmJjgZX3CvyLHd4Minc9@bw3dJukhuWBkdb7LHp03uCDnGdMWahGn3H3YU01p9IjHuJWGQRW/TQdQnUv1rH4TxNz/IBSLz7lPWR6haplmxC1alwGrtUMZPlERS/qWAcuF7/iwiEDdapeiNKOZnUQ1h3c98aIiSLfnlwZvfKHb/lct6AzqSeWcz8MaoPoBeJlOaWCpM4d48ZkbEaqUMmipy32eIZWWpJwbGRsJXdRPa0khrYmpJ6LMsn24mP9a/DSdY1ppsoKqjJvJNkMHcUREEeCkisR00rl/ALzyeZSacG3vQpMoB0qkNrl9eB8znaXzK@KVu1@5ip1TeRAht2PTnIgZFtKeKsAjcXKYhLy6g7pVREI9cpyXteABVvUVqZm99iphTJPJ1gSfKwQWVMkNFTc7yeRx1r/u8up7pyJrigxUiBJrJ2d3RXt0kJRB@8aPjmGSzwuXosGW2t66RQDl6G3PqZ3NxuwZ6S6zbMwI7C8dTcbsDICKPvKFmMRHGUSyZQ0N@5FrvxMPEvr5Lguvb5xr7lxwWnnHjadca@5E15tP7IF@/fPlGwEzHY/8@IKiBqu7l8w6wtBjfpSVkzfmt8Mqu6fmgSPPAmFg5Pfn//ecE@r5tjbl7lqHOOl4NDiN@SpYxpvcap0SlF3G725CfiwA1@B/Q8FyqrdxgNbib1jP2jsPbkQUjUXpD0iDALobKEGduuzN2QlBM@PJ5N1Ghw@tRWmJHfmjAl7fNljAgXinzUP6/j8qNVCPJUEmaBrE7sWST4PO1RaXu@cKdxdGZtRHHzHT8b4i6zAZs3RXk8yIv5J1agT@ynZ/Q37e2YAnZ2tp52d4tH/fAQ4jt@3xXbpsU0cV4HbjH1piGh1MM716qXEzqz9B3LJ/3gf11P3E9bp1m9LjTbX5BDg/Qze3/@n5/75v@IwgiuaeBvN9J7k3kIbdF@R9TwioDcfszjif8wHMDeF9X@h4148aGmvwbig3c8Rl1j/M/70PEddZoMCNel8jrXj9J7kfyvLuR5GmAwPNiNDH8j7IOUocfYrmdycbwXp/wY2NdiGfSkabUedwRe9wTlxle4GZwjbzULj@BNcTtW65KGcIjn1mPvuWoN4RaNkP31dNrzMT3YmTvRJiZXgK83GYj0v070XuvimE03vLIAN/8tGwRs9UpTGU9yyI3FC0CjZeVhC37kGwumk/0CxMEtveRLwo6NLuympYtm0gi//zHpOzJZxxNVehnKFpmEZ0ioWSex6fPJd@S@07iQiOCBHZSICs@48cdlp36uTeXnTgqo/evD56UbVR5loWXPQpoG0LIZWNqChHQR4uKXwozibnchSXfFdZyTdBpEUbs1J/kc5RP@z46I9GmLVsHSJISGPq1mHZxk71hE05bXBSsnwsUV0EcH4symST55z9k84hJEIPUGC/Zi9OMDY4MHtUWHZsnK7klkXOexiWIRjqGZxTQyBliCJffdebNXdHVpiYzlj0dsZF93Y87@8xAU0dncdTi2f5Uq@68@8uHQWvkXLHQQrq3qFIVelN/MB63M7XJliD2JUdtuzndwvR6tsbU6kItl0XnPuKYY@VT0t@YRmNhrmWPFoojI@F2/FT0aKIRj8jx6SwGjUGW41UXpOXZjVPVUCeE6AGM/Zxt0YEl@lwXI3nIxOgIEBwFCqsu2Fc2J2cxPNbeauFNaiSgHjd01uXZZkVsveLjQuSRk47Z6TpiPdVDp9cXo5RPYjoFGXwaTkZWtlTLcLj4odVZkN4eWrRrdn99dVE1@62vXzO07ap6WbNFy6A@U1n1Yu/N3u7@wc7B@33o8FIvtbdXHu2JYyq3PLaEIxfZcleWyqMTTtFlilNKQha0qxJVUkP2SX2xAZZbGRw2mgZTuqKmuY2Grm8cuO4uEH/gsXTwJQ6ulKVkcXksszQhduhcNoToEldOmK2aO1rClLZQACNQ2yJSb0ZWYGRxk@0EGVx@MoENx2c5l12M7OdWTZ1aYVXXXK2iyVSFYDPndnsOC58i3XhHErkq4ATl7K4TriG3/vW3v8tTrWGO8X@V4ynG/yPHnyzS0u1jECnjSjWklg9v9liGuCIXHrqLjTXJFg3OHRVoaENo8EQohMBvLHdNRht8gDphA@iSPJScUrDj6Uib53nyzLIoDs/iYGqKepwvYAb4tIkS1PpS0BkjNpK1vbX9qI1yjxsnS4KiHZ5RcSgJ6vozpjLlxE@co7HHer0eU9H9BtzZtqUerar7qaserQStAlaRMXvAgAOUNQbm@iWaVnUbbZ1QmeOwWrvGRjbCsTQLdrQmBgDR6XMk1QFZNIqbQlPUWfNFzuDM6dkyFSERoE8LSU/ipHlJyAAhSVtXlVuuC3kxIypA/1qaLJ3uDi9hcIb/vcNJIoz/W44Hw5ZxNbrrRPQON1mVhQfxMY@yb5wEGTlB@OebZ0J@ib1xJrT8hECs9a5x1@Vx1dq/1GpbBY81XU@51S1sMl2WbysWm5i3l7YMDFBt2a7AWvRPBkD9iMjp58/Yi595FPEzpsHxQhf2dAsUeaneXP6Dq7k6l7xtkd3aRRDDx6qWLUKyfQnlHw3ZMB9OhxFZwD6zvrdMy77QqoFzZmGD6H2tOnfajW690ahGda0akYs8fEiR/LIKDzw0VVNdAMioBrqNsAePdaqRXXV7WnXidOoCA68IlBdAuMos86LqXlrVh3CCJr6knPYV16qZTnm7ZZrtS8j3OfajqtUM3eRCU5m6oNNcYl/1Gw2SwawekgBX1nC/AcnhU/uWyB92GXesWWiL/Vm77lW//15hbEttb6usa1knQ@2FXUF0H76qDdxpx/wyqlWY2n6k9uzokVKx6kddNjuezT6q/cHjx/Wmvf2kzpov7Fq7@UVn7DtcWqej7@3v7WlMqZwtvrO72w9eKJWj3hH7Tqk4SqU3avQGZt8Y9QdK5aJyflkRBozYoy2mozI543qPssfiXYOuwat@Q17R5C3uPWM02Hu7u7O/2@z0jEpnOd5//7LSxoetzuudH@UrzXfp9d3uzqvf3h80O69@@8ubD7vv90b9hmkYhtkfQYZ3ix/6V1dXDda4qud5XjcXSuVVf/HeMnrg91YHhIAm8K9KZXC2OFu0gtZJq33cPsbAX7Q@L1rz1rytTdrt9qLF37fGi9a4FbcnuHP8tEIM/dZ00Zq1olZEQDEG3qLlYTDFfUZTU1D5jB@/1SLirZMFuARtcbVa2qdDXX@0rT1pPC1/nAe6q1S@KsKwmsZP3EBT28NFZ9pRdWQO7akOF2x3dd3QWpRJHumf2r2etr2l9/vadkfHdE0bXuD3UqfbQNNH@iUG8levVYj1V8dy2lbnkbNwng561caLhvECl9Nv9MrH84pQqDmylMPDVzsHO4eHTrtiWUrFHJpqu6MeHtbJpjYVY3HAzSCese5TRcVFYM6Yz@ABhJBlHMU233N5wflpUZzy1eWhAfj8GaElSaw6QCd8itT/3TnLEEZQ1tS8mtF@rnafoDLqPlaVCmINHcP06MAqNud9hQ4bNewGXeBr@lHlaFirWxfUx2jnun1p1WtHR0q1RoA1Esfoxo/iSrVaVXp9tav@Zvb6JC/9J5gEJ/nFCir9zmMT9VmFWY9/iq4ePfW2ul7tUbeW2PCZJ99PZjO/8/3Rd1/bX7erllWrdbYYcyrScu3HeiV7MKqIwNppVz4dfjp88aDbqffqCDv9LPvY6XSePn2qdrZ/t6xvJQDMrqIjGuE0K8K7wuNO6v/iUt0UrUIkBr8UiMYrrTFSW@CPSW/XvklVbn4S/4rGN4XkEjqmAbodrymKOVang6rBSGcXolL0p0yjWaS4tqxYZWGeF2nEWrYigei4w14NwYXMzBwCoI8UHjXfadvM7xExPBFVSw50LTEaDg0DHmlCCn@k2yuYlSR9YG/IsoHfaEjwSymWXI8XTuSy5dzqFeKF1GV6Womt3wBAkQ6Y2rBVK5f57ywDaV1bUWiyP72MG/hIIPpyTUKE9WT5fW2KS6WeN0NboWXXE1v5WfP0C0ps9lX48KH3KRmEI1sPnZyejUZoXyrHmi9B6rkTOkbbTiCsnQ8aDX/khPrPWiKED50WgMGbKGf6xcrSkVOaK9Ob54PIuIpGzdeDqNEeNYtm/aNz3nSdVnOBP6itGTS/QHlLVWq5c96IbLeHP8qx1zSROFnDta99IpRjLXDOB@7Iael2AMRG4zUWAzmzQdBojHQwDzB5G9EOHj50G0F/YQeGoRPUp@7z14Mcg1HDofdnmttbPD8fFMB/puHpgE2gQ3jgXbcB6EE@GzqW5luLLmVckHgLiBc6Tv3j8/rHuvPgwflgYYSjplT/s9ba8CT8goTf9BGt/nHTsYRKRNOpqT/4z34w6xlTm/A@KLmZbGBKCesfMZOsd8Pl/wM)

Edit: Japt is failing in the Test Driver. So [here](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#PVJdc5s4FH22/kJfFOQdJDDoA2zHa6D2rrM728lMPEm9D8UEEywTEgfSYqc4cfzXU@G0PVdzOdI90r1c6Q1B2NV4T4MOpU9zPBoiiOB8oofJSthfIx1BjbuaNyxcgKixcGB2n2VftCDs943OsHdqwM5oqPPOVwJhSwELQaZX0ymGAO3q1tDpnYwAWngL2ALIB8iLTC@0AysKQoBe0PMrgvjxW15AtwsJxDc7STyAEKovzQbhJDDfUSzPlfesKJyen42vzjrCs5D4xa9mfyGuFrrin/Hf79Mm7jTTy7Px5GL2uSMmF//@9//ZbBoFpm1Zlh1EqobL@o/gcDiY0DwYm83GsGuAJkE9o5an8p0TpTiqG/keoHBX72q2Zk@M3/N7RfKa3dXslt1yvOSc10zO2E3NbljJl8pLZexB0ZytapaxghWNqFQkrVmqyEr5rAmt1Cl3ynLGmsPZU62yrPkRjOHrmBC3h0/NwU/zT0gC0B407dtgLJ@SNdb4vBYroZGkWOIBKb9h7hBiYabm0CXX3PNwr0uCAPcEUWEdz1/UeCWNCzGJyKsi74PoqEm996nPqXD92h@EXtscmdZIwQ9M7@fnIzo21I4oiOPJ@PM4jn2OKAXIntsaF1ocG82dDtOyqMq1tNdlBp0B0BQamX8jM/UCmg1VJeWDlNNEbqX8vt1@l7@R5lVyd5c8KlBDSZdylRey9Qyr/FmWK6inusU/as6p9qfm9DWA8iJdb5fSqzbLvLRvA/CQ5AWGEJLjfkwWaDHXDfryuN1U@JkMX6mhLxagrTdCvSnHckq3RO12G3iB5mgXthc09UrVzKbwpv7jH6BA9O0q2SFI@5@KgztIu06qu47@OFRv5vTDMsty8WHR2vN9r02prosuhD56vzneJ6g6iZBMb0soOLqOr@PRiSMMz6CUBlX1RQgxGAw00Xt7@wE) is a stand alone Japt link which outputs 7.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .010337 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1006 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.

### I Did a Bad Thing

Have you ever done something you knew you’d regret, but then did it anyways? If you answered no, then you’re probably lying to either me or yourself. We’ve all done it. You know it’s true.

I’m trying to be better though. I knew I shouldn’t have asked the compiler its version. But I did it anyways. And that’s how I arrived at my first answer for #45 C (clang).

Yes, yes. I know the rule is “you may not use a language feature that returns the language's version number.” And I know that `#ifdef __clang__` returns a boolean, not a version number. But you know what; we can do better than that - you and I. I may not have broken the letter of the rule, but am not my code. I can understand the spirit of a rule… and that is what I broke.

So let’s get back to printing sequential integers - the right way? Ya know what I mean? Maybe one day an unambiguous rule can be written that tells us when we are and aren’t asking, ‘what version are you?’

### Driver Updates

I found a different directory for Whitespace on Tio. This is apparently where the Whitespace option points when you’re switching languages. So I changed the test driver to the version in the dir `/opt/WSpace/wspace`.  I did this for Nim and INTERCAL in a prior answer as well and forgot to document those changes. Those languages broke so there was not really a choice. But for Whitespace, I believe the change was for the greater good. More on this below

I also started paying attention to the debug info in Tio. I really hadn’t been paying attention to this – specifically exit codes and I’ve kind of introduced a bunch of errors to the polyglot over the last several answers. And I think I’ve been violating this rule all over the place: Your program must run without erroring out or crashing. But, you know what; we’re trying to be better right? So I added the exit codes to the Test Driver so it’s more visible when programs throw errors while also providing the correct output.

Also, I went to the Tio chat room, and asked if Alphuck could/should be added, and it is in Tio now. But it’s a little different than the old-enough-to-be-used-in-this-challenge interpreter. The interpreter that @SnoringFrog and @ais523 dug out of the dark side of the internet was not case sensitive, but the Esolang.org entry @SnoringFrog found seemed to indicate that Alphuck was case sensitive. My interpretation is that Alphuck, as it is understood by the world council of people that case about such silly things, is case sensitive and we’re using a weird version. So in my view Tio is right and we’re wrong. 
Also, the Tio interpreter is  a BF transpolation written just for Tio, so it’s newer than this challenge. As a result of all this, I wrote another test case abstraction for Tio that converts the polyglot to all lowercase and pushes it through Tio’s Alphuck interpreter. I probably should have just gone with @SnoringFrog’s Alphuck interpreter from the beginning, but here we are.

Like the V test abstraction, the Test in the Driver is not *the test* but is meant only to help in testing.

Edit: @SnoringFrog also points out that Tio’s transpolation is 8-bit where our interpreter is 32-bit. So a known limitation of this test abstraction is that any *use* of a number that’s valued outside of the 0-255 range will present different results.

### PicoLisp Explanation

PicoLisp’s code, like a lot of other answers, uses a `#` to initiate a line comment. This one uses block comments that are initiated and terminated by `#{` and `}#` respectively. So, the PicoLisp code addition is `#{#z}# (prin 45 ) (bye)`. `(prin 45 )` prints the integer in question and `(bye)` ends the program without error.

I should note that `(bye)` can be removed and the program will still produce the correct result. But then the Exit code Tio provides in Debug would be 1 instead of 0 – and we’re trying to be better than that.

### Japt

The main problem with curly brace comment blocks is that Japt thinks opening curly braces contain code. Code is good normally, but Japt thinks you’ve got a screw lose when you tell it it’s going to receive some code then don’t give it any (e.g. `{}`). This is like telling someone you’ll call them back and then never doing it. It’s just rude… Becky. ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)

I got around the problem this time problem by giving Japt something trivial to do, while I went off and partied with PicoLisp. This is what’s going on between the braces here`#{#z}#`. Japt is taking the ascii value of the next character (with `#`) and that is a Incident token that I needed to detokenize.

### Whitespace

This has apparently been broken for a long time. Actually it’s always been broken; I just didn’t know how to see it. It actually had the same dang problem I briefly cause with PicoLisp – I wasn’t telling it to end. So I did that. And then I realized how many random spaces and tabs could be golfed off as a result. Now, Whitespace prints it’s int on lines2-4 then it hits 3 consecutive line feeds to end gracefully. Huge byte savings!

### Fission

It was around this time that I started poking around with the other languages looking for bad exit codes and Fission was being managed like an 80s era soviet reactor. After trying to destroy each atom created by INTERCAL and Minimal-2D, I finially stumbled on this piece of information in the documentation.

> `*` Causes the program to terminate and all atoms are destroyed after this tick. The mass of the atom that caused termination is used as the exit code.

So how’d the atom get mass, you may be asking?

> `"` Toggles printing mode. When an atom is in printing mode, it will print every character it encounters until the next `"`. Once printing is done, the atom's mass is set to the number of characters printed.

Cool, so all we have to do is decrement the mass according to the length of the string `12`. That’s way easier than what I’ve been doing. So, `_` does the decrementing here`"12"__*`, which puts our error exit code to a happy zero.

### Pyth

I’m not sure I can correctly explain the top line anymore. It’s a code salad.

What I can say for sure is that Pyth also had an error, because I took out the code that told it to quit. (This really is becoming a theme.) Pyth’s quit command is `.q` and ideally, it would just be placed as early as possible on line 1 to quit out before any random command were attempted by Pyth.

Of course, the `.` can’t be executed by SM/BF, so we have to encapsulate Pyth’s quit in SM/BF jump commands, like so `[.p]`. Easy so far.

`q` is also a an operation in evil that we’d rather not execute, so the `f` jump command had to be moved earlier in the launch sequence. Problem though, the old evil solution had an `a` before the jump, which is lexed by evil as well, so this also had to get transplanted in the move.

So, `[af.p]` will work right? No. Pyth throws an error at the f which happens to be an instruction that expects a number to follow. Ok, I’ll throw a 1 in there to get Pyth to work. But now Whirl takes a dump because I have too many `1` before the Whirl/Incident line. Fine, code is now `[af2.p]`.

Next, 05AB1E didn’t like one or more of the commands involved so far. Its polyglot long, `"` based string get started on line 2, and starting it earlier than Turtlèd’s `"14"` would throw a bunch of multilingual stringy chaos throughout the polyglot. So our Pyth quit command has to be thrown into a standalone 05AB1E string – meaning it will have to open and close shortly thereafter. Only thing is Pyth uses `"` for string declarations too, so we use `'` to declare the 05AB1E string since Pyth handles this instruction differently. And now we have `'[af2.p]'`. Cool.

Meanwhile, the `D` in line 1 was locked into its current placement (or slightly off to the right) for Minimal-2D’s alignment and Turtlèd didn’t like crossing the Pyth quit statement in its current state. So Turtlèd’s jump code `#` really wanted to shift to the right, but Minimal-2D didn’t want the D to shift to the left if the `#/` got removed. I tied a pair of place holding spaces here, but that made Trigger crap out. Then I tried `##` as place holders, which would just make Turtlèd to a double jump. But that caused Pyth *and* Trigger to fail again. So the ultimate solution was to put `# #` before the `D` and another `#` for Turtlèd to land just prior to the string it should read.

Of course this still shifted the D two columns to the right, so the Minimal-2D `L` on line 8 had to shift also to catch the code path. These 2 columns ended up getting filled by incident token I wanted to detokenize, which gave us the `ndL` on line 8.

Solved.

`# #` could probably be golfed down to 2 characters in the future, but I’m not touching it. Not today at least.

### INTERCAL

At some point after golfing off a ton of whitespace, I realized that INTERCAL’s code had 3 `<`s and was followed by `>>>` to balance for Perl 6. Meanwhile the BF and Minimal-2D code was preceded by `[<<<]` to balance a bunch of `>`s for Perl 6. And then I realized that the INTERCAL code could do the balancing work for the BF derivatives.   So I transplanted it. The `[<<<]` space was already well hidden from BF/SMBF, Underload, and Retana, so most of the safety measures in INTERCAL’s old placement could be golfed off as well.

The one voice that complained though was Prelude’s.  Prelude’s code, which I haven’t looked at in months, is `46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)` and it likes to live near the end of the longest so it’s parenthesis can act one dimensionally. So I moved this bit to the longest line again, mostly for safety, but it still complained. Then I moved the parenthesis that hid INTERCAL form underload up to the Whirl/Incident line and placed them so they’d have roughly the same columns. This worked.

I don’t remember why, but I felt compelled to move the `a` that followed INTERCAL to the end of the Prelude code, but as I look now, this can probably be golfed off.  Maybe.

Next, INTERCAL put some extra `1`s before the Whirl code, and I preferred to not re-work the Whirl/Incident solution, so I set out to see what could change in INTERCAL. And let me tell you, INTERCAL has some interesting error messages.

Eventually, I found a way to swap out some `1`s for `2`s while storing my variable *inside* of west hyperspace… I think. Also, I found that I could golf off some Latin vocab while maintaining sufficient politeness if I was willing to take a compiler warning. I was, but now I sound insane. Worth it.

Oh! I forgot to golf off the `UP`. That can be done for some reason. Note for the future I guess.

### Befunges

INTERCAL, Turtlèd, and Pyth all had a `1` that couldn’t be removed, and Befunge-98 had 2 `1`s, but we were only allowed a total of 4 before the Incident/Whirl line. This meant that one had to be cut from Befunge-98 somehow. And then it occurred to me that 77* can be used to arrive at ascii code for 1 in both Befunges, so I reworked the solution to leverage this common functionality and cut a `1` from the code. I should have done this before now anyways.

The only tricky bit was that the solution had to allow passage from the `D` for Minimal-2D code and not kill the Fission reaction with a `*`. The end solution ended up being `77*,;68* ,@;'1,q`, which is similar enough to #41’s solution that I’d refer you there for a deeper explanation.

### Incident

Moving INTERCAL ended up shifting a lot of tokens to before the Incident string, which changed the balance equation quite a bit. I ended up removing all the detokenizations I knew about and adding them back, one by one, to make the balance. Were now at a 10:17 balance. (10-17 = lucky number 7.)   The only detokenizing strings in the polyglot I’m aware of are the `z` in `{#z}` and the `nd` in `+ndL+` and these both serve the dual purpose of place holding for 2D langs.

### Where to go from here.

By my estimation we are darn close to the VIP score goal. Between Cubix and the last ace I’ve been keeping up my sleeve, we could be within a couple ten thousandths. IMHO, it might be worth throwing the Cubix card, but pulling one more answer might be a little better. My gut says Octave is still in play, and the curly brace trick used for PicoLisp might be the secret sauce. But I’d bet there is another challenge to overcome C/++.

[Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)’s a Cubix resource I found somewhere along the way.

Good Luck

Comment: Also, TIO's alphuck uses 8 bit cells (otherwise [this](https://tio.run/nexus/alphuck#@68bbadtowsCsXZ6XJkFianJmSBQnJj1/z8A) wouldn't work), whereas the compiler we've been uses C++'s default `int` size of 32 bits. Currently, the program isn't affected, but making use of the 8-bit-ness of the cells technically wouldn't be allowed since we have no evidence of an interpreter that did so that predates the challenge (although I agree that TIO's version is more true to the spec than what we have).

Comment: For Fission: if you check the comments on the question, @ais523 confirmed exiting with a non-zero code intentionally is acceptable, as it's different than crashing. So there's no need to fuss over the exit code before calling `*`.

Comment: @SnoringFrog I didn't realize that about fission, but I don't think I would have done things differently if I had. Consistancy is worth 2 bytes I think. Thanks for the Alphuck info. I'm gonna edit that in for visibility.

Comment: Octave's requires block comment indicators to be on their own line. That was enough to shut down my attempt (mainly japt being the issue there), unless I'm missing something. I'll try something else in a day or two, for now I've just golfed out a few characters.

Comment: @SnoringFrog Oh. Yeah, that would shut it down for me too. Dang. We might be able to get there in two if we have to. Just gotta we golf off like 15-20 bytes I think.

Answer (score 9):

## 49. [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 995 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)" 3//v\D(@;'[af2.q]GkGGZ'#)"14";n4
#/*` "[!PPP(22)SP(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@ ␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=<xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDOiipsiis{i}ii@O6O4/oh]>+.---.>][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[kGkGx/0l0v01k1k(x0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100^_)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"__*
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#ssseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp/*/
#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(   )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*'``
<>{# }//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#< >"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\
#ss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#ss*///nd^_^_Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpJc9tIlj43/kJd0iDLBEgCIKnFCwlasi3XqDZrLNkVYZKWQDBJwsJWWCRKMhVznYk59L0vc@z/0df5Ff1Har6XCS7aXFWHjhg6CCYyX749X7735N9K9GEHkX8x8aOMZTzN2CjxznhispcXbMfx0q3WhqIIqCQa5a4XTlg25cwL4zxjY8/nqeI6GeuyuMBi0oCVWMKdkQRTxlHCaAsLTn3mMTeO2dB3pqbLfE/AplFA6xlP4oTjmbKQ8xFLY@56Y88VdBifZTxMvShMTea5p@zc83024j42rIi7dSBjebo2JUmZyihSGD5ufIvV5VuZAybkC3F57CRC3IjFQvaF1OeJE8dgUimxQzCeeQFPmZdVUsad1CMdYkvKw5HQVLzUbsSccF1KduY5zAG/eSJwpzzJIJ4p8LIpTzhQOkR8kjgB084TL4MKSJG77IA7CTtKONdBBQbgqevE4OMGSRCLiEJGgpjCUJ1OZe/tmwoMJneYTpwppWTj6N@/Vxxm2qx83MbXVtW2svfza3ZV7tMYXAAZjBonmqMz@5qlVr/P8Z01h9YkmSvAqkArPrOiOLOA2UkysLcaGWctM/bXyLLOLUusOZGEGsEWbD9kH@pCLjdPEg4uVip1TiGyH4UTaBOiJnlI2gjZdgMGcKNwlNYZP4POolBaKDoX@j2aejBZSgZxhlCP45Lm5QEQ6sQRgOcV@lzQTSM/F3DYmWbkftAJthLG/TH7wMaO59MWrBMqyXXC09zPaE8ejsjugRfykckWbLjRiICC6AzkHCAVEzgzwdpJE0wBGGaIhKi09M@//m00mQDPrutGyahw1g9sFLl5AIYdwawDRyR3jULHF2wBrk7U5XYQOHN8b@RkRD68KEgIJgTV8yj3RywCweTcw8GaOmc4jOMxdzMuXTzKM/BYZ4FzKuODJ/0WggfOEIYVBARtIbbBdl7BSi6XDmMEeTZ@yox4j1VS65P24rn24lGfgzfd1Ktly5q04W1mVUzhrfI1x/mwu7Inec@RF9Ep8uNpjpiBlTCNEU0SUqbrQJyUgkqGmFdnQ6FoEYng6OKInvNKwtkQ53ohmPAR6QO036BzW2BY2XQBd9PF@GjNw@CdcLIsvRMk/OgchAVvFDjh0yERdyYOSGWFQLtSIElRzNwU7TSEpxO2IWdPjaEH65AfINQUxliTEeAbLQkDbNJ6a4cicC6AxZUhemVJ5o1h5AB@m1wwl9NhwKngMs4RkVw4RurBj6Ixaxitra3fMX6WWLvGR8sxLq2v2piEv2XmXTbm58x3wknuTODIUYgtjuvyOCtOECRJM5yR22FQTBpFTDfTqVLeuU1bxLYi2q/RoOgjrVdEaIfcHooKoGrDxylnTjIRJ5GNvATnxb@4TR0AZ7eIqycEcoOBE/UBFhYXE5yMz7ibZzhucOTzqedO4bvEXSgPrIyOt8ljap06Qo4xXpImZprdxy3FtJZTxMaDKAyy6F08iPqEqntjQhh/fUIKiJv3kG59hKrFNStOwTIVWMoOZXxPl0jCf82hXPieNwkJxAmXV/RaFPPSsIKw7qUeNESXLfnl0f5bit2/cJlvQEfy3lkPvBGyD2wvLlNaWChM4e40YkbIKgUPmiruvs9gy0oTVwyMtQtf1U1oSyOtiaUFos8yh7p9@bHuXThBslJnPVUd1HHf@CnMHea@j5c8FMdB4/oV/MLlaWrCuXEGTcocwJ1a4/r8JmA2TaJzxud6u3IfuT9pkFf50Jv9P7SIS3zJJ6RaM4OY@iN2uAP4LzbEHXowxX6IWwbx91JcByGFtzzIfSeTGYEb5dDz0hy4Ghy7IS14BB39iCyJ/ejR5TVGTrXKtUV6PqOssq@o8UU2jcKNm@FHXa20ZHr3wQpwG5nxxf0Xr7qOSmz4yQtPI@LNChaj44bZ3LqBAuXB3Z1jL52Kxw3QO2zdXRG702A4Fo97AEJyxVseLxaCKIwkcWjICx3rnfgxEWLv4@BmJLtB/iWHjSfceLZhDb3QGvLxQ5BvXr7cFzDj4dB7CAhqoAJo8XsPWJIP79MSEpjpnZuO3dDzUZ5kvjGyMvrl//sfI@j7rjWmzkWKlPd0OTgO@TlZxhg/aJxiK72Ix/2G/Jz7KId@B4frUJrr@MvB/bies3cc3o6EJBRVEDj1fRxkqAwB5q474yT4@Ygvfu9HKnR488KUu0MvMODL22ZDGBCvlARQKvYQllu3vkRD1UHiR87IkvWax1cWlbrnM2cShRfW2pViJsM/wOriYmarAi2b5lkun1SV/Z7tvJi@XzuCBWRja/dlc6/4eQAeTGw/5Lvy2CSILsYb3zm1hjQ8HmN4v6hSmMSboARc/D4E9sth7LjcOk/p5163@QnplI/C@vDn94cHX/UfgRB5VuLL573o9kMXl1qY/T4mSOmLx59xPOEHruPD@zak71FfxFhTk3dLsb4zvKBCfvrnfYioTmo1ZkSramXVdonjhze57v2bZGNG7HMj1JP8924dXB1eAHFbo7Xhgz7hRcaqJkqlI42pCLwn9jhnDjNc30nhGlmhXX4Ga4jH11yVbgiXfGY1@pqj3mJqUZc@VNqsdsaeG@H2joWZ6cXHy0OX2u3sYYWGGm7isdpKb4W/vubOiK7a6686bORmVFHcoS1SjXeiBbOsidJ60TnCnJcUnYJ02YwrrVZZ6ASiUqTxIotpy3I0nYoeBMrGEYLq@9ATWaQbJbKokpW7uMD@8fdR0ZqZcNTWgZciYZqE1ExE5TSNzl9IugX13Th2qLVDOHCMfZlnGq92WXruZe5UdmSQmL1/c/S0KKeLxiZeDiiarnEh5cbSGDw4GReVn@RmFHGp0YLwctdCKBg0D0J27o2yKXK3Qw8VsijXFyUkOEkIDHV7RBaps3024hRfRJr8OUdm50fRqcjOiZN//F02EbAIZOAa4wV50dVao8jgzk1RubsyjVwgueRJVIBopGS4ZQ6NXMAfuJzXmTt1RHcjMZmxqO2JjKzvX@0eMgPFPfVkqdRve2OtvPvuuw@9xsC@ZoGFXMOiRFnoTf3WeNJM1TpbgLTnHKn1@nIDy6vVClPLM7UQi/p/ot21dCrpcEyjsTDXolYPROtQ@B0/F7W6aMiEdOqoJ4dyJM3wqgvUsodnlzUkKQEqD@MwY1vUuOZQCUay2cioFQyKYkt5xr6wKfmK4bLmVgNvUiE@tToCe5Uarmfj1ms@zMUddtYyWxu2EKd8bHe6YpTwUUTNsN6n/vnAShda6fdn3zZaM6gtSgD@2KKTs/fz66uy2W18@ZI6F0xV55W2KFrU5yorXx3sH@wdHu0evT@EGud6ocCDossrOpZO0cGGL@fp4mQW@qNmt2g4iIY1bRa4y3KrxLZPXifOwOI4g8Ja0WJKb9Q0p1bT9bXe@94M8Q9OSz1Q0cNUFpxFRYduYUUc0qksRVGfLv0wXVaVJMKYTpEPQ1DZJK7@lCzByOgm2/VTeP1oBDMOLzIuqyhZSC6rSbXEyo65lKLOVIVgU/tupwZWPsd1557IzWUBJzCn9zU7@9z651//Jhuc/Qzj/yzGY4z/W44/WaSlux0xyeNSNaSWD/sHLEVokYIHzmxNJlkiwr/DHJV0AA2eCYUQuGR2Je8Kj9b7AH3CCFAmuSl5pqDHk4E2zbL4uWVRMJ5E/tgUBQGfwQ5wbBM5sPVrTv1mHCZre2t7s4l8kxtnC4SiNTKh7FQi1PXnTGXKmRfbJ0OXdTodpqIC97m93ZaKtMrOpw31ZMloGbCKjNs9hj3YstqBtW6xTSs7taZOW5lts0qzwgZthGRpF5xqTQwAotN0WOhDRdiIClVRcc9nGYM3JxeL@wiXAQrFgPQk/uqwQGQAkcStq8od3wW/WBEpqHfjrjTXzaD@QmAiYX2u3uc6DB7yP/d4Tojxf8lxr98wrgf3dcyXvrN7tzGu3W5rkyxs5zCMqCp5A16Z1rJaG1ZzW187J2qBCtzSqfgClDgHOFcu9z5Hcbr7am//@7cHh3cauwKychuswirdTq1vmPXeYDmo3OPzyxz7KDoFx1/pcBoZQXiX671Or9i91utcTOFi0To3WNVlG3ZN5gVxOG4xU26qoLqi5Cp3irF1NhbZ8ZLo@s67wi7iHhynqAbhi/TnNGq@4XLwwMnODzwM@QXTcKwCB97q5MihE72@@HtufdmBX5Pk34ri8raz7VWu/AhHqmy1xTXUnsOvTvqsn/XH/ZCcq31hfWOZVvtKK/v2hYV4oHe18tRu1jaqtVo5rGrlkE7E48d0e83LOHDHpmqqMwAZZV9vI8zjgNrlsF12Olp5ZLeqYgdecTFcYcN1aplXZWdulR/Dv@uYSTiFEa6VU51SlYZpNufg73PkhWWrHjjxlaYydUZ/yCDyZa9WIx7M8jExcG31D2vgHMfl0BL3ZbuIs9YkaItwVLnppb/9VmpuM6Zq89bGox1dZRuWddZ/re20Kz1n3DJ/HXx3@t13HyslXW1uqu1wUylZ1ROm9h4dHBxorZZ@eKB1n7An1Xp7@2m1jm3N@g77Cz7sV6XU/Qvs193YfrSDwUnnRCl1BrVOz@wag25PKV0ppcu5UlJKdmf2rkaf3utuTX5@xLdjDHrxwY97u4d79VbHKLVev623Dt@/LDXxstVarNAMLW9g/d3e7uu374/qGH63/2Hv/cHrt54Xp56XXnlzz9t5u/1204qmg27NNAzD7A7AxrvZt93r6@saq11XsyyrmjOl9Lo7e28ZHWIEAALY6OuA/6KUeqXeKbQysxp@46zRPG2eajMMvVnj86wxbUybo2azOWvw943hrDFsRM0Rnhz/GgGGXmM8a0waYSMkoAgDd9ZwMRjjOaGlMZB8xj@v0SDsjbMZyPhN8Wk0Ph3rm9va09qz4p/9SKfk4osizKsxjZ8hZ9DUZn/WGrdUHTem9kyHKzY3dN3QGnSDbuqfmp2Otr2ld7vadkvHckW70q6ac50ePa2hD/Q5Rn2aqpTmJTp0Idvc0nETcP2LZTet1qY965RrOzVjBx@7W@sUPy9KI6Fe01KOj1/vHu0eH9vNkmUpJbNvqs2WenxcJZbblI1GPjd9hN6NZ4qKD4HZQz4BMdqQpilHqsUPHJ5zfp7n53z5eYUa6PNnhJ44tqqAHfExpbuXLEWYicYVt2I0X6gbT5EXbjxRlRJCETXBOtQujMxpV6FWr4azoYvtmn5SOulXqtYVVXLaJdPbc6taOTlROt2rEpsTO3NlRNXp5jMhzZXSnHe6GJUrhKpCc8ZGtBmVyuUyXJ111Q31ranY9F8maAfJJyQEotKXaKt5HX7fLj2PKxublT4J@/Sb0WTitb5hJ1@aX7bLllWptLYYs0vSts0neqnbemIi7y0NirlNzA1KIta1mkBRRaAKR5@OPx1/bLVaz549U1vbv1nW1y4WrC5j7Jgj/OTBfUF2N/F@cii5DJeBFoOfcsT0pXIZadf3hqTeG3NS4@tT4r9uYE4hvoQpaICq0K2LjJdVqZvYG@jsSqTT3phptIp7tinTelnAZHkSskZbkUDUk2ovh6BCzsBsAqBJiqmaZzfbzOsQMvwiFBcU6LPYUbNp6PNQE1x4A729hFly0sXuNV7W9tdqEnwu2ZLyuMFIii3Xlq9gL6Bq3NWK3fotAFQygKn0G5VCzD8iBtIFbYmhzv60GLf249bRFzIJFlaLxfzKFHOlmtWDtkJiV@O28oPm6ld0G7avg8eP3U9xLxi09cDO6LdWC9pz5VTzJEg1swPbaLZjMNvOerWaN7AD/QctFswHdgPAoE2YU/1qaenQLsyV6vXLXmhch4P6m15Yaw7qeb360b6sO3ajPsMXaqv79V@hvIUqtcy@rIVtp4MvXcw3NBHbac1p35iiLaeab1/2nIHd0Ns@NtZqbyAM@Ex7fq020EHcx@LdjW3/8WOn5ndnbd8wdIL6tPHiTS/DYFCz6f255nRmLy57OfY/1/Brg4yvg3nsu2kD4AN/behYmm/FuuRxRuzNwF5g29WPL6ofq/ajR5e9mREM6lL9zxsrwxPzM2J@3Ue06sd1xxIqEdW5pn7rPf/WrKZMrcP7oOR6vLZTclj9iJV4dRrm/wc)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .008457 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1057 bytes)

This program prints **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/). I’m not positive this doesn’t have an error, if someone could verify…?
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Cubix’s cube shape viewed [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)
- For Deadfish~, can be tested to output 48 [with this](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.
- [Polyglot Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)

### Octave Explanation

Octave is the last of the languages that I initially spotted as a possible inclusion when I set out to  opened the polyglot up to lines of code that didn’t start with `#` in my Rail answer. For those that have been following along, I’ve been talking about Octave for a few weeks as a possible inclusion and I almost gave up on it when @SnoringFrog rightly pointed out that its start and end block comment statements had to be on their own lines. This turned out to be a critical piece of information I had missed in testing, which previously lead to some poor assumptions.

But on a whim last week, I tried to probe Octave’s requirements and developed my way into a little Japt/Octave polyglot. [This code](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@6@skMClXM2lXFXLpVzLlZJZXKBgYo4kopxQY1hjpvL/PwA) runs in both Japt and Octave to produce their respective numbers.

With proof positive of Japt/Octave co-habitability, I set out to see if there were any other hidden problems, and yes there were several issues. But first, let’s go over the Octave basics. `#{` and `#}` are the begin and end block comment statements, both of which have to be on their own line, with nothing before or after the statement. This means that the print statement `disp 47` can’t be tacked onto the end of the block comment like so many other languages do, which was the driver for its placement. Here is how the Polyglot looks from Octave’s perspective.

```
# Several Line Comments
#{
Block Comment
#}
disp 47 # Line comment
#{
Block Comment
#}
# A Couple Line Comments
```

A language of note for Octave is PicoLisp, which has the same command to initiate a block comment, and in fact both share the same `#{` to open their first block comment. But PicoLisp’s end block comment is `}#` instead of `#}`, which can be seen on the long Python line.

### CoffeeScript

The big surprise of looking at Octave again, long after noting it as a possibility, was that CoffeeScript had a similar problem to Japt, in that it treated a `#{}` in a string as containing code between the curly braces. And if you’ll remember, CoffeeScript handles literal string declaration the same way that Pythons do. So deep in the center of our Russian doll of string/comment declarations, where Octave’s print statement had to live, CoffeeScript didn’t want to see Octave’s block comment indicator. That’s a problem.

Instinct would suggest that the same basic trick for Japt should work for CoffeeScript. But there is a difference. CoffeeScript has `#` based line comments, so if the line following Octave’s `#{` started with `#` it wouldn’t be parsed by CoffeeScript.

Why is this as problem?  Well, the next line has to have a `}` to terminate the in-string-code for CoffeeScript and if we put in a `}` that’s not hidden behind a `#` it breaks another language. Care to guess which one?

Yes, you in the back…

You are correct; this is a silly, complicated mess. The answer however is Brain-Flack. You see, Brain-Flak needs balanced `{`s and `}`s, and by hiding the `{` behind a `#` but not the `}` causes Brain-Flak to bomb out.

So we must expose a preceding `{` to Brain-Flak, and this is what’s going on here: `<>{# }//`. The `#` inside the braces is the same Japt trick I used to party with PickLisp in answer 45. Then the `}` closes the brace for Japt while leaving it open for Brain-Flak. And of course the `//` at the end of the line is the same Thutu placation trick used whenever a line doesn’t start with a `#`.
For Brain-Flak the `{}` instruction pops the active stack, which is bad mojo for us because that’s where our answer lives. I solved this by preceding the `{}` with an active stack swap instruction: `<>`. Then once Brain-Flak is done popping the empty stack, we switch back to the answer stack here: `1}<>//`.

Altogether, this leaves us with the following code snippet to integrate Octave:

```
<>{# }//
#}
disp 47#//
#{
1}<>//
```

### Everything Else

Well, there wasn’t really anything else. A little tweaking for Retina, Incident, and Cubix, and that’s it. Nothing note worthy for once.

Happy Polyglotting!

Comment: It might be useful to note that Octave also has `%{` and `%}` as block comment markers, and from [this quick test](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@69czZWSWVygYGLOpVoLZVr8/w8A) it appears that they can be mixed with `#{` and `#}` (which I didn't expect would work).

Answer (score 9):

## 53. [Shove](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Shove), 1158 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPZ (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][
#x%+>+=+~tt .
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1k\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
'\';echo 50;exit;';print((eval("2\x2f5")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"*'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///89^_^_Z222999"26
```

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpLc9tIkj4P/kJfyiDbBEgCIEhJlkyClmzLs@5ut7SW7IkwSUsQWCRh4dUAKFGW6djrbuxh7nPZ4/yPue6vmD/S@2UV@NDL3X2YiKVMoICqyszKdyb9a4k@7DAOrsZBnLOcZzkbpv4FT032/Irtun622WwpiliVxsOp50djlk8486NkmrORH/BM8dycdVlSQDFpwEos5e5QLlNGccpoCwvPA@YzL0nYWeBOTI8FvlibxSHN5zxNUo5rxiLOhyxLuOePfE/gYXyW8yjz4ygzme@ds0s/CNiQB9iwQu7VAYxNs7VXEpWpDGOF4eMlt0hdPpU51kR8cVyeuKk4bswScfbFqS9TN0lApFJiRyA890OeMT@vZIy7mU88xJaMR0PBqWTJ3Zi50fop2YXvMhf0TlMBO@NpjuOZAi6b8JQDpEvIx6kbMu0y9XOwgBi5xw65m7LjlHMdWCAAnnluAjpuoASymDDkdBBTCKrTqewfvKpAYHKH6Sa5Ukpbx//@g@Iy02Hlkza@jqq2lf2fX7Lrcp/GoALAINQk1VydOV9ZZvX7HN@ZfWaN07kCqAq4EjArTnILkN00B3mrkXHRNJNgDS3r3JLEmhLJVUPIgr2O2Pu6OJc3TVMOKlYsdc9x5CCOxuAmjppOI@JGxLYaEIAXR8OszvgFeBZHUkLxpeDv8cSHyDISiHsG9rgecV4agGAnTACaV/BzgTeLg6lYh51ZTuoHnmArQXw9Yu/ZyPUD2oJ5AiWpTnk2DXLaM42GJPfQj/jQZAsyvHhIi8L4AuhcABUvYDPhmqUJorAYYojFUWnqn3/923A8Bpw9z4vTYaGs79kw9qYhCHYFsS4UkdQ1jtxAkIV1dcIutwPBhRv4Qzcn9NFVgUIQIbBextNgyGIgTC99GNbEvYAxjkbcy7lU8Xiag8Y6C91z6R98qbc4eOieQbACgcAtjm2w3ReQkselwhjhNB9tMyPZZ5XM@qg9e6o9e9TnoE039WrZssZtaJtZFa/wVPmW4rzfW8mTtOfYj8mKgmQyhc/ATJQl8CYpMdNzcZyMnEoOn1dnZ4LRwhNB0YWJXvJKytkZ7HpxMKEjUgdov0F2W0BYyXSx7qaK8eGahkE7oWR5dsdJBPElEAvayHFCpyNC7o5doMqLA@3JA0mM4s3No51H0HSCdsbZtnHmQzqkB3A1hTDWzojlraZcA2hSemtGEbpXgOJJF72SJPNHEHIIvU2vmMfJGGAVXPo5QjIVipH50KN4xBpGc3PzN4Sfp9ae8cFyjc/WN2VMh78l5j024pcscKPx1B1DkeMIW1zP40leWBBOkuWwkdtuULw0Cp9uZhOlvHsbt/Bthbdfw0HeR0qv8NAuqT0YFYLVRgArZ246FpbIhn4KewmubmPHgotbyNVTWnKDgFP1ARIWgQlKxmfcm@YwNyjy5cT3JtBdoi6SBiu94230eLWOHS7HGC1REzF293FTMa3lKyLjQRAGSfQuHHh9AtW98UIIf/3FtyG7WXgP4HhJIjzU2lvTck3oXsE0RPMjyiTg/hahW1jWMr1Y8hMM/oECU8p/mUJg0Gd/HNESN1qG/TXP6GdRBaHCz3xwnQI46frx6wOKB3/hMocB32UsW3fmMTIabC8CNE0shKBwbxIzI2KVggZNFfH0E8iystQTA2MtiVB1E3zSiF9iagHok8zLbgdU1r27TqCs1FlPVQd1xLAggwpF0yDAwzQSJqZx/Rq65vEsM2Ew4K1J2QioU2tcn99cmE/S@JLxud6u3IfuDwrkxfTMn/0/lIhHdMkrTrUmBvHq98jhzsJ/sSDu4IMoXkeIXPDpn0WIichlTsNp4OYyy/DiKfi8FAfCjes0pASPwaOfkHmxn3wKiCPkaav8XaT8M8pU@4qaXOWTOGrddGnqaqYpU8b3VogIZyZX9wdzdR2U2PDGj85jos0KF6OThmlv3gCBkuPuzpGfTcTlxtI7ZN2dEbuz8GwkLvcsiEgVb2m8mAjjKJbIwSE/cq234mbCbd9HwU3veAP9cw4Zj7mx07LO/Mg646OHVr56/vy1WDM6O/MfWgQ2UFG1uN@zLJ2e3cclJEWTO9GT3eDz8TTNA2No5XTn//sfQ/D7rjQm7lWGNPp8OTiJ@CVJxhg9KJxiKz2Iy/2C/DQNUGL9BgzPpdTZDZaD@2E9ZW85tB1JTiQqK1AaBDBksAwO5q46wxKC6ZAv7vcDFTy8GYTl7sgPDejyltkQAsQjJRaU3j0E5VYmIcFQxZEGsTu0ZA3o85VEJe/5zB3H0ZW1FlLM9Ox3kLoI9mxV9OWTaT6VV6r0fkt2fkLfb5lgsbKxuffc3i9uD6wHEVsP6a40mxTexXgVuOfWGQ1PRhjef1R5mNQfo6xc3B9a9pejxPW4dZnR7V61eYMULUCxfvTzu6PDb@qPAIjcLQ3k9V5wryMPQS3KfxsSThmIyx9RPKEHnhtA@1pS96jXYqyxyb/F2MA9u6LmwOSP6xBhHddqzIhXFdCqlZMkD2/yvPs3yWaP2OfFqFH5b0UdhA4/xHGbw7Xhgzrhx8aqzsqkIo2osLzH97gXLjO8wM2gGnnBXX4BaYjLt1SVIoRHOrMafUtRbxG1qHUfKpdWOxPfixG9EyFmegjw8FBQu509rMBQE09cVlvpqdDXl9wdUqj9@k2Fjb2cqpQHVOZ3eCNZIFAJtqYXZvwQ07z4kr4PhvhJfMHl9d4oJDKgt6LbtCz/snrRJMM7Py2aItmy71hazbLIDUVRTONFctWWlTdwUrsFFfIQvv5d5Ivk1otTWT/KJoWIq//4@7DoQo15nrHQz5DHjSPqm6JInMSXzyTeAvtekrjUxSIY8C6BTH@NF3ssu/RzbyKbT2DJu1fH20XnoOjh4uGQnPwaFfLcmBqBBjfnosiV1AxjLgVdIF7uWhwKejYNI3bpD/MJUsojP/K46EwsqmVQktKyKE9jUpQ6e82GnNyeyN4/TZFwBnF8LooGouQff5f9EkwCGKjGeIFeNPDWMDJYmS2aFJ7MbhdAPvM0LpZoxGRYyxQcuYKacvleZ97EFY2c1GTGoo1BaGQr48XeETP2WYXaz9TVaPsjrbz39s/ve42B85WFFlIgi/J3wTf1e@OJnal1tljSnnNk/OvTDUyvZitMLc/U4ljU6hSdvaVSSYVjGo2FuBZtiVB0SYXe8UvRlhC9p4icAbUfUSVlOR51AVq2K52yhtwpREFkHOVsk3r0HCzBSPZVGXW9qcSmLeUZ@8ImpCuGx@zNBp4kQwLq6oTOKmNdLxKsl/xsKkLrRdNsthxxnPKJ0@mKUcqHMfX9eh/7lwMrW3Cl359932jOwLY4xfLHFlnO/s8vr8tmt/HlS@ZeMVWdV9qillKfqqx8ffj6cP/oeO/43RHYONcLBh4WDW3RnHWLZj10eZotLLPgH/X1RW9F9OZps4BdllsltNekdcIGFuYMDGu1lCm1UdPcWk3X135m2J/BLUNpqd0r2rXKgrK4aEYupAgjncgKGWXzUg@zZbFLRxiRFQUQBFVzIiPJSBKMhG6yvSCD1g@HEOPZVc5lcSfr22WRq5ZY2TWXp6gzVaG1mXO3KQUpXyIKe6dyc1msE5Cz@/q6fW79869/k73cfo7xfxbjEcb/LccfLeLS3eafpHHJGmLL@9eHLINrkQcP3dnamWTlCv2OpijwQ3DwQjCElktiV@ddwdF678FPCAHMJDUlzRT4eDrQJnmePLUscsbjOBiZok7hM8gBim0iNbd@mVJrHcZkbW1ubdhIg7lxsQAoOjZjSpolQF1/ylSmXPiJc3rmsU6nw9QMWRd3ttqSkVbZ/dhST5eElrFWkX67x7AHW1Y7MNcttmllt2brtJU5DqvYFTZowyVLucCqNTHAEp1eRwU/VLiNuGAV9Rz4LGfQ5vRqEY8QDFC/hsQn8QPLApABQBK2rip3dBf0YkZkxv6NWGmui0H9Cy0TefRT9T7VYdCQ/7lHcyKM/0uOe/2G8XVw348DS93Zu/sbgHa7g09nYbtHUUzF0ivQyrSm1WxZ9pa@ZidqAQrUklV8AUjYAezK4/6nOMn2Xuy//uHg8OhOD1usrNxeVmGVbqfWN8x6b7AcVO7R@WXqfxyfg@JvNHONnFb4n9fbun6xm3qmza415BcW9ZYU01rMIL5onRsU67LxvHb0BQ3Q3@JN2VaBfIXQU@4kZ@vULHL3JdL1nXfPvHB/0J@iVoVK0g@I1BpEjPBBye6PPIr4FdNgXaELpXWnyPBTvb74Bbu@/M1h7ST/VpS@t3Vuv3IdxLCsstUW0ag9h3qd9lk/74/6EelY@8r6zjKt9rVWDpwrC25B72rliWPXWtVarRxVtXJEhvH4MQWxeRl2d2KqpjrDIqMc6G14e9ipU47aZbejlYdOsyp24BHx4RobvmaWeV1251b5MdS8jjcpJ2/CtXKmU8bSME17Dvo@xX5Utuqhm1xrKlNn9NMNoS/7tRrRYJZPiICvVv@oBsphNUeWCJvtwt1a47AtvFLlprL@@mvJ3mJM1ebN1qNdHcBbllW96L/cbVd67qhp/uINKiVdtTfUdrShlKzqKTs8Pzz8AJNp6kdq75HWfcKeVOvtre1qHZvs@u6f8GGHlcpmq3L0sfKLUur@CWLstrYe7WJw2jlVSp1BrdMzu8ag21NK10rp81wpKSVn1nlbo0/vZbcmP/t7P@HaMQa95PCn/b2j/XqzY5SaLw/qzaN3z0s2HjaXTzTVwtPb/b2XB@@O60255c@v3@@/O3y198L3/SQbDrNhPBl0a6ZhMMNk3QFImH1f69ac2tc8Z1C5l93ZO8voAPFPSuktLTSMvm52B1@UUq/UA6/mzUbQuGjM7HP7vL9xsHWw@yY@WP07OMC0P2t8itPGpDGxh7Ztzxr8XeNq1rhqhPGBPcSd468RYug3RrPGuBE1Itu@Aefhf@FB/OYgBqgY2/JZIyeojRHu44ODNwA2AuJP@PMbjQaobFzMQG9gi8/HE73R2NjStms7xZ/zSKdE5YtS6RdJ1WajzWd@3q5ItdE0fuEGmtrsz5qjTVVHONZ2dCi43dJ1Q2tQeN7QP9qdjra1qXe72lZTx7RamalxWtGutWt7rtOlpzX0gT7HqE@vKqV5iQw6YhubOoIN179Yjm01N6AL5dpuzdjFx@nWOsXtWWkoJGdaysnJy73jvZMTxy4RGstSSmb7rWo31WqFDtOmnDcOuBnAwbd2FBWfElY5Z3wMfLQ@yzg@4aHLp5xfTqeXfPl5gULr0yc3qcLw2yb5qWZzZ3tze6fV3K5v72xvbNpbm5t1u1m3n2w/2WnU7Ya9bW9tb@7Y9e2NndbGxsYOZjd3nlhVpTTkI8rIE5bBBcajSlIx7Gdqaxupa@uJqpTgJql92KFGa2xOugo1yZnGdKtqkWWopyW1X6la11RswgPq7blVrainqgLone51aWtzTgeaK0Mq7jd26KAwLHve6WJUrhC8Cr0zWvFGXCqXyzDCt121pR6YikP/i4V2EIcEjwColH2JN@2v0Q/t0tOk0tqo9J2SLEM0@4le6jafmEjDSwP5UtvAu0FJqE7TJs5m298Nx2O/@R07/WJ/2SpbVqXS3GTM3iKWbu98PPl48qEJpu7sqM2tXy3rWyEQs8swMOLwkNPwvjiwl/pvXEqDo2UswODNFGFnyWNGTA78M@LyjXeS8euvxP@nwTuF6CIOajRA/erVRW7OqtSO7Q10di0Sf3/ENJpFRmDLAkSWWvk0jVijrchF1NRrL4fAQjrBHFpAL8nta75jt5nfIWC4I1oUGOiz2FFzaBjwSBNU@AO9vVyzpKSL3Wu0rO2v1eTyuSRLnscLh/LYcm75CPJC6ht4WrFbv7UANRfWVPqNSnHM33MMJDbaEkKd/eFj3NqPwKgvziRIWE0W71eimCvVvB62FTp2NWkrP2qefk0Bu/01fPzY@5j0wkFbD52c7rVa2J4r55ovl1RzJ3QMu52A2Hbeq9X8gRPqP2qJID50GlgM3AQ506@Xko6cQlyZXv/ci4yv0aD@qhfV7EF9Wq9@cD7XXadRn@ELttWD@i9g3oKVWu58rkVtt4Mv5Q43OJE4Wc1t33hFW861wPnccwdOQ28H2FirvcJhQGfWC2q1gQ7kASbvbmwHjx@7taA7aweGodOqj61nr3o5BoOaQ89PNbcze/a5N8X@pxruDtAEOojHvpsyADzQ1waPpfhWpEsaZ0TeDOSFjlP98Kz6oeo8evS5NzPCQV2y/2ljJXgifkbEr@uIVv2wrliCJaKPoKnf@0@/N6sZU@vQPjC5nqztlBRWP2AmWVnD/P8A)

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

Want to learn more? Try the [polygot chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)!

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .007778 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1224 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 by running the official interpreter on my own machine.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- <s>Shove was tested to output 53 using Ørjan's interpreter (which is a slight modification of my own that handles I/O in a much better way for this challenge than mine did); it was formerly available at [this link](http://oerjan.nvg.org/esoteric/shove/shove), but the link is now dead. Luckily, the Wayback Machine had saved a copy.</s> Turns out that that's no longer needed; a) Ørjan's website is back up now; b) TIO now supports Shove, so the program is now part of the main testbench.

### Explanation

#### Shove

At this point, the challenge is mostly just about finding languages that predate the challenge to add, and then finding working interpreters for those languages that also predate the challenge *glares at PPCG rules*. (Anyone happen to have a pre-existing Sansism interpreter handy?) So I decided to look down the list of 2D languages on Esolang to see if any of them gave me inspiration, and stumbled across one of my own.

Shove is basically a 2D language inspired by Underload. However, rather than using an eval command `^` that works on the stack directly, stack manipulation instead works by dropping the contents of the stack directly into the program, shoving aside things that were already there, and then letting the IP run into it. In this polyglot, we're ignoring all that, and just outputting a string literal without doing any sort of calculation.

The really nice thing about using Shove in this polyglot is that it *naturally* splits itself off from the other languages; running polyglot #52 unmodified in a Shove interpreter causes the IP to fall off the second line of the program in stringmode, complaining about an unterminated string literal (`"…"` and `'…'` are both strings, and apart from that, the only relevant characters to Shove are the `v` in the first line and the `>` immediately below it in the second; I'm pretty glad that the interpreter ignores what it can't understand). Well, that's easy enough to fix, and dropping an apostrophe in just before the final `q` lets us create a capsule that only Shove parses (besides the languages that parse everything, obviously). `'53'S` is our Shove program to print 53. We then use the `^` command to change execution direction to upwards, causing the IP to fall off the playfield and exit the program. Simple enough, right?

#### Alphuck

Shove's print command `S` closes blocks in Alphuck. That was the easiest non-empty fix here; just drop in a `P` to balance it just before the Shove capsule, and everything just works.

#### Cubix and INTERCAL

Normally, you can just find a point in the program which Cubix control flow hits naturally, and move the Cubix capsule around into its path; not a lot of Cubix commands have irreversible effects, so you often have a lot of choice. Here, though, the *very first command* is naturally `O`, which will output a zero before we can do anything else. What a pain.

The `O` is inside the INTERCAL code, at a point which is fairly difficult to pad out of the way (it's in the middle of a fairly long keyword), so I decided to rearrange the INTERCAL code instead. In this case, I moved the politeness to a different part of the code. I also changed one copy of `DO` to `FAC` because I needed a padding character for Cubix to prevent its capsule breaking up an Incident token that's part of the main program. That let me drop the capsule into the Incident/COW line, which is to be honest probably the easiest place to put it.

#### Fission

Fission is an absolute minefield here, and even with the help of a Fission debugger I couldn't figure out what was causing extraneous output in the Fission program. In the end, I decided that in the interests of keeping the polyglot going, I'd try to terminate the Fission program as soon as possible.  This isn't a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, but in Fission, it may as well be; there are way too many Fission landmines (atom bombs?) now in the code for the Fission code to sanely be allowed to run for long.

There are two potential ways to do this; add something like `R.__*` to a safe place in the polyglot as a sort of fuse that causes the program to end, or just remove the `__` that sets the exit code in the existing program. In the end, laziness ran out, and I decided that an intentional exit with exit code 2 was the simplest way to stop having to think about Fission any more; after all, it's within the rules, and we can always fix it later if we really want to.

#### Incident and Python

Nearly all the changes I made have zero effect on Incident, so I was hoping to get away without any incidents occurring. However, removing one of the **three** copies of `__` while fixing Fission created a token imbalance, fairly obviously. Given that I created Incident and thus ought to know it better than most of the other people here, I looked for a zero-byte way to fix it, and did so in a rather indirect way; Python's division `"1\x2f2"` can be changed to any other fraction numerically between 0 and 1, such as `"2\x2f5"`, which causes `"1` to no longer appear three times in the program. Now, that wasn't a token anyway, but the *reason* it wasn't a token was because `12` also appeared three times in the code, and the overlap `"12` in the Fission code disqualified both tokens. Remove `"1`, and now there's no overlap, meaning that `12` becomes a token, and rebalances the code.

And that's pretty much it. I hardly added anything, and thus hardly had to change anything; this program's only 8 bytes longer than the last. (Sorry for reducing the VIP headroom so much. Hopefully there's still space for whatever you want to do, and if there isn't, we can always backtrack on the VIP score a bit and make it up later.)

Comment: The Shove interpreter link is back up now.

Comment: I have a feeling that a year later, the three of you guys (SnoringFrog, Chance and you) are still going to be answering... good job, though!

Answer (score 9):

## 74. Archway, 2051 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1011)(22)S ␉\4n;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d@O6O4111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}() )wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h> 
main (  )  {puts(p);}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72" )';end;
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O. /++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-x--.
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''         16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005061 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2135 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLd9tIdl4bf2E2ZZBtACIBEKQkS@JDkm1p4p72SLFkO6dJWoZAkISFVwOgSFmmT7bJyWL2s8ly/sds8yvmj3S@WwU@JFJyd05yTmgRKKBu1X3WrXtv0Zd2Ovz11wJ92Gnk3wz8KGOZm2asl3jXbmKwFzfswPbSrWpNkjhUEvVGjhcOWDZ0mRfGo4z1Pd9NJcfOWIvF@SwGNViBJa7dE2BSP0oYDWHBlc885sQxu/TtoeEw3wPscWUH8GkUEEzmJnHi4pqy0HV7LI1dx@t7DsfF3EnmhqkXhanBPOeKjT3fZz3Xx4AFAU4Zk7FRuvRKoDOkXiQxfJz4Hrnzp6ILmNCdsezGdsJZjljM@Z9xPk7sOAaRUoGdgfDMC9yUeZmSMtdOPZIjhqRu2OPSiucSjpgdLnPJrj2b2aB3lPC5UzfJwJ7B52VDN3ExpU3IB4kdMHWceBlEQMI8ZKeunbDzxHU1YIES3NSxY9BxByWQRYQhI0YMrqxGQzk6OVagNDHCsONMKiS183/@UbKZ0WTFizq@TVmuS0d/fsVuix1qgwpMBsXGiWprrPmNpWan4@I7sS7NQTKVMKsEqfjMjOLMxMx2koG8RUu/rhqxv4SWNe5pYsmQBFQPumCvQ/a@zPlyRknigoqFSO0rsOxH4QDSBKvJKCRphGy7AgU4UdhLy8y9hsyiUGgoGnP5ng89qCwlhdiXEI/tkOTFIuDixDKA5eXynOFNI3/E4TAyzcj8IBMMpRlf99l71rc9n4agn6YSVCduOvIzGjMKe6T3wAvdnsFmZDhRj4CC6BrobEzKX2DdBEurjRMFYKgh4qxS1z/@8tfeYIB5Dh0nSnq5sb5nvcgZBSDY5sTaMEQy1yi0fU4W4MqEXQwHgmvb93p2RujDmxwFJ4JjHUcjv8ciIEzGHhbW0L7GYuz3XSdzhYlHoww0lllgXwkf4Qm7BeOBfQnFcgQcN2dbZwcvoSXHFQajB6Osv8P0@IgpqflR3d9T9592XNCmGdpG0TQHdVibscFf4Ul5zHDeHy70SdZz7kW0ivx4OILPQE@YxvAmCQnTscFOSk4lg98rs0suaO6JYOh8iY5dJXHZJdb1jDFuI8IGaLxO6zafYaHTGdxdE3N7SxYG64SRZemKk/CjMRBz2sh5wqZDQm4PbKDKcoYOBUMCI39zl7WrEJZOs126bEe/9KAdsgO4mlwZSzwCvFYVMJhNaG9pUQT2DWZxhIteaJJ5fSg5gN0mN8xxaTFgVbjCzxGSETeM1IMdRX1W0atbW99RfpaYh/rPpq1/MR/VMTF/T82HrO@OmW@Hg5E9gCFHIYbYjuPGWb6CwEmaYY3cd4P8pZ77dCMdSsWD@7i5b8u9/RIO8j5Ce7mHtsnsIagAotZ9rHJmJwO@ElnPS7Be/Jv72AFwfQ@5/IlA7hDwSX6AhNnGBCNzJ64zyrDcYMjjoecMYbtEXSgWrPCO99Hj1TJ2uBy9P0dNxFitZ1XJMOeviIwHp9BJo6vzwOvTVK07L7jyl188PrOdBmsmjuYkwkMtvTVM24Dt5ULDbn5GkQTc32zr5itrHl7M5QkB/0gbU@L@MoLCYM/eICQQO5xv@0ue0UtDBVuFl3qQOm3gZOvnr09oP/jgihgGchd72bIzjxDRYHi@QVPHTAmS6wwjpodMyWlQZb6ffgZZZpo4vKEvBRGyZkBOKsmLd80m@ixis/sbKmutwnGUSpm1Zblbxh7mpzChcOT7eBiFfImprnYLW3PcNDWwYCBbg6IRUCeXXG16FzAbJtGYuVOtrqxD9zsV8nJ06U3@H2rEIbrEFVwtqYG/@i16WAGcKUKWc9GtQHDZvYwC8vPsA@eY6H2RYG/oYz@Q4ptsCE@nO0y2m1HsgqQ7nkQBnQjOVa3OAzpFMT5HXqjeKk@fPlX2lJZSRmsfrQa19qlVQmuft3TeIjiDWnxEmbeot81H0LuuMm3PZp5oXVLthKLWL16s2u29vVq3bLet/F6lu4bNBHsHoHW6YR5FazapqWlyawxGjcu@JNg/h3J@QsjHfvJoJ@4jQFwkDtIcWUeShTBqd32pvOipilj1vRlAfEZ8sz6KkJen4gPeeOFVRDZqBrPWRcWwtu5MgXxndWTfS4f8cgd0hazVHj46DS77/LIGYC8PAxBTUI5EcuGujCKRKILljzlYEIWRIAXy8kLbfMtvBnaPdfTcddJ3iHnhYs0PXH23Zl56oXnp9h@CPH7x4jWH6V9eeg8BQShE9@y@BiwZXa6TGWKz4comzu5I/XyUZL7eMzO6u//1rz1If1U3Q/smRTR/NW9cQGikJ73/oKryofTAL@vV@nnkI9P7zhyOTRG87c8b6@faY29d2D7UGvIED5T6PvwJRAY/t2rcWBf@qOfO7usn5TK8GwuI0aEX6LDsbaPCFYhHim@493lglnsBjZiGEp/Ej@yeKVJRz11oVMjendiDKLwxl3Y2I7n8DaTOYg62yD2z4SgbiSslnN/TnRfT97EFmUNWtg5fWEf57QF4ELH9kO2KZUOuWj/27SvzkpoXfTTXsyqYSbwBstvZ/SGwD2ex7bjmOKXbg/4jHKUxVyRvPQSG6DHxxfUhEC90sLOGi8ZDgGDR55ffY3XcCBzbh@nVhOFRvUdfkpF3T6q@fXlD@9nw9xsQYR2USkyPFlnYopwUxw8Pchymw/E0nd3d9aNF5YlP4ERImN3v7UTYTrwAfFd7S80HLcOL9EXSlwpzoiBgnQeyr20EBb6dwkCyXMzuNdTCL48ZLO0Tzsi3k0XrMXO9R9Qs8X4od1uMjD0nwo4u7JMefG@tiYYU7N0PjBbTUFWRXxZD6Sn3na8Q@9D2@@1RBxo5GaVMD9jOb/BJIluhfHDJLozoIaE50Zi@Dy7bYXTtiuv6vejLWqp@g8/RfW4SiLhXh/ec71nrBy@Fx8FlvS@8WktV5vhr3@@xN1GUIF1NWdWoPKqetcZ8Zrw2fjJOjDN25vlR@qg8kKynqbiuN@UF6GXi2aHukA0vt9cPW0sY39fYIb8@oGDbH0T@9s7AtHFZK5uzUdInx/6YWB73UZb1XR81D2Wi0MrvD7r1K/x9zz6oEgI/7lFMM2@ut5XvOLQ8AXiYTUT9NHI9i8eVnbmJJel6IQJ3DnOYOMOxffOYqHka8pbXmufFn7Scl8jxzkvykmg6P3UovA6dxOWloFlyywpUoBoF8KhZlBiMw6mqXSppmiQG0dochACbQfHKLxXfRFE5ZXCSGYdFAtVus@LtZK@yZ01Zk8l7Mut2xay8DHQ0iXnJ9q0Y2i7a3WZR0XWlqHTCPVZROKiL7H89qH0Hru/xm6BzwToL7YDX@6g947QuiorwYFRJHtphD/Hju9DjebsTJaI0JuqvPFb/@996eYF94ILJwEttH4KgI6EocIfReF/gzbEfxrFNBXqaA2GLLzJ7/eUhS8de5gxFXR0O9t3x@U5eFM2PqPBwSoHjEhVCqehCSprZmVCaoKYXucIqcsTzUTOmsGuNgpCNvV42TA24otBxedF1VggEJQmBhVkSkVWV2WvWcymG4oWJzyPo1o@iK14PIUr@/jdRCkanRyZE7Rl6fjaxhJHBa1m8/uo40QhUzyb54iZRDqKSkLH3jiCRG9i0K95rzBnavEYNS9RnFVpCI6q0Lw/PmH7EFDpZo4Jt3eurxcO3f3zfrnSb31hgIq0yqUbE5Sb/oD@3UrnMZiD1KdnVcncF3YtehcnFiZyzRac4/NBiblRiNTGV2lxds4prwA@AuN25Y15x5WX1kEILOlkJU6wPPGp8arFomkUV@VjgZUw/y9gWHT@6EAla4siI0YEeVQ9pSHHCvrIh2YruMGurgichEJ8K1kFzkQUvlyHMV@7liIfr11WjWmtydooXzUaLtxK3F9GRRvtjZ9w105lUOp3JD5XqBGKLEoA/M2nlHP351W3RaFW@fk3hlGR5qtR5mYiWd/H29PXp0dn54fm7M4hxKrgsHEdJYC9cBBlB7GP3GEY@PyOCPBLPTb/vNp5wvyE9yQFVlRVt1mBWhcFDPZk7llyssi4XRVP0cU8y77vXmbuPvsdyV8dOubZzxSrpspsrzwyAhIc1OYJfnREPw7ld4644OzJrgiEdDHHwOcHzp3WM3e3l8ELg@/QMoedsLENxVhdQ64GIVwGc0y1gBJFrmZj@L1EeYx/5PuUE9T3KASx9D/sS4uPD1z@9e3u0insJbQ6zAjK3kKVD@aMJdnn4wT63cDr6mdlNlB/dzRwD/P5Q1JNtf@Ha0nlpmCypT47Zx9qmRcET55QWNyM/YrBDP4Uj7fXgGS5vMnIs8KiiGjwvCcsFCMCY73NlJksEmzZXj3DgOMaIxZxPYnCRw/GZ03WnoB3X/Mdf/ipOPjsZ2v@Wt/to/4dofzRJQKtHZYLGuWhILO9fn7IUu5VgPLAnSzzRhkEbkheOEBsFkOA1FwiBC2IX/C7mUdvvIU8oAcIkz0fOjuNzk646zLJ4zzRpf0dk2zd4Oc2dQA/wlQaCQfOXER1Ewz@b21vbm5YJIvXr2YT8fGNAtR0xoabtwYSkay9ufrp0WKPRYHLq2L7b3K4LQZpF@2NN/jQntAhYSYQCbYYxGLIYgb5WPkwt2iVLo6G0ChVLYd06dnmhF2wUKm8ARKPXYS4PGTtRlIuKjkrcScad6s0sxEF8EUYsIDnxnyPMJtIxkZhbk6UV2wW96OEFHO9ObGksq0H@QGC83LMnrzMdBgv5zzWWE6L976Ld7lT0b911R@lz2zlcPTFX7593Ey/s4CyMqKZ3DFqZWjWrNdPa1pbWiZxPBWppVXzFlFgHWFeO632O4vTw5dHrH09Oz1ZOfDmkch9MYUqrUeroRrndnTeUezY/E@mLY/PszYvjmSCXqcq77lO1bvL7hD2A7IOomK2i4h0riKzKb514kb@vZWSR3S8BvhSJ/QpWVbudtruNVicsrKD/uu7nGAVjg36BgVYn5T/GUNgaB/N6Vgc8j65gHo@cM@sZQXhflk@cZ1VEOs6ttsyee23S@aNkLOqLclFt3KFWE2fiQgYz9PAT@ZuiJQPvApcjrVRplgkRmXI0p@TOyLmwiecTkdnxn5TYIYL6xHMEdMqdq8j/@O8fkAG8zhZJAxIRLCiP50Y3PA/AMp9XPXoeL4jZyU3OwbznzA08/XxGDy36xSEfnBBSX6Qf6dD3Lut2sz1h8yOwx87/jDT2vUylg7eJQfkVuFE1YsBq@C6d2zV2u/khIZud5ZX4ceDpCPI6jWK2yGlfubPWW6Q17NUIk8MCXPbjKABcn9/euuThXfbnSMdgyFGZEdEGFjXnwQh6W8BuDN1Jzxtgl1C1MhzKD5a1OEi0tRJyUQU@VIjqj1TKWRbM7zr8XJKY3bYNL@y5E1UZK9pel6SD98r4w7WiySs2wE9g8@PY3v2j2Nnat7N8Ec6PMZcXzixgAfL8EASbCP1Ajo6@kSh4sOmDP7lhCJNRQXYAA2H2CHwmWnn2K83y/Dc1S37hn/Izlfu7xJFy60fYC4tmnack9Sk2hE8d1sk6/U5Iu0L9xvyDaZj1W7XoN29MbORaSy0Om1aptlEqFcMNtRjSVvbsGWUy0yJ2ygtDNuQJgPSir9UhT@yszWJYL9oNtdhrVjf4CDyWStotBnxLTeO2aE/N4jNsTGW8SYR1qMVUI3VUDMOagj7SUNEsB3Z8q8pMntBPkwh90SuViAajeEEEfDM7ZyXupjpnJs@d6nmAZA6CmRnfMYZffy1Y24jVp2pU2q/Wnh7oTDY3Oq@u60rb7leNX7qnV6en/6J1VKXw8kS2NuX6hikVzI3K1@em@enTJ8QMTGvrSrettp4/3yjXt3c2ygd1xSofWBXL0tRqVTtjTzqbYf3JkyeqdaooWzXl7CMdpu8/xT/@h8/8ka5P@Zv8NQdZ/TzVmPrLRCq0nsBIattPD558kgpS4aJVwsfg11Jpb@9A1/UJvkZpXyp8agCm0Z1OS412o2G0WpOW3m21pcKtVJhMpUJVJu43pEJz0njLJ2i/ymcq/fITLg29245Pfzo6PDsqVxt6ofrqpFw9e/eiYOFha/5EXTU8vT06fHXy7rxcFUP@@Pr90bvT48OXnufFaa@X9qJht3VwUDJA4IHR6oKSyQ@lVqmZZRn7@WLDsBOp8Ko1eWfqDWD/SSq85bB6RwP0V6nQLrTV/ep@teJXrivWlXX1JjpZ/J2c4L03qXyOksqwMrR6ByfbJ5uWZU0q7rvKTeVmUgmiE6uHpot/lQBNr9KfVAaVsBJa1p3JHv4LTqI3JxGmijAsm1QymrXSx31wcvIGk/WB/TP@eZUKETmpXOOv4lv88/GiolUkpILdre24uv1LmzuVrd1u2514WVdmZaXTVrr1gpl2OqawYrkKQ6Tu6fTi4tXh@eHFhUm50aRRLB2U9AN8mq1SI7/tF3otEpshKSqytbijYIuw67yiVKSj2rbVLRVv7b3RlDwQ27A2NO49tir1@sZh3t5EO2/u1OtuajucgroiSFJVF9udKludSbXPqjLfRXaxhq1ao6Fub2mt1vYWHrd3NF2tUOem9tGad1W1KJGViRwlCrudin/q7bSh8o9G/zSNXubXlnarNgACmC2NP4sBqsa08YcPH@j7YXw9Fi3eEO8@zDuXH3gDn@sHxq42kCBiw2VKYVogjxyyzS0N8b2rbW6rO6Xd/F/zqQby5ZpSA/myUpBm6mpaBWJXKhj1t7JVlRVSX51qVZHvGj6i6NquJOMjNS/dgRdKjdathA3nEkHEmD2vIKDwfTthUb//VLI90YXNE1kHEu/U9X1K3yh2HEeJ3xsjniE4ZNIJs@l3@1hYaeriE5za7sh1x6PR2J1/Xnrpnv35sx2Tt8P@V5EM2quq1d2drZ3dWnWnvLO7s7llbW9tla1q2Xq@83y3UobH27G2d7Z2rfLO5m5tc3NzF71bu8@lghv2vL5pwrVYssx4o@f2qVY32mFybadTkedvYpYixon6Sqzo1v5oR95@Lu/JteeAQGRGP2Bo0E89ImPYYhL9aoepcMKM3dLKUWOtPsX8M7rnmBkWgGEwfHVdon6xH6jy86rMNKUOuPrKmORqD2lrQrEzB0doub0r02uAiBnYtiUVplKPDio3d@vkS6eNllRUiDKlJhX0WrQZFYrFIlzveUuuyScGM0v/o49BrtyQmoQctlGQCXMh/RptWd/CH@uFvVipbSq1TrMg1qT1XCu0qs@N1L4pdMU7pm4@1xie@FKuWgU28f6v/qKU9cf8M19nK6tuqbXmeXwd8P0HTO78oTcYeNU/vPn0FQmIoswLU9b2N70h/hq4vDwRvMvbW7IGG0/TjxcfL7AzbjG5uiUzVjIZkhnzX6qw5t3d7YL0q2k@lsSgdx6D9V2EJ6NgXRB2mHhvbKoahfNADI03I0Trc7tlZLgU3g5bd99xY77ziv9nDbyTiC4yJZUa8NZOmZey2Ab33F2N3c7KoCr1UiVOmxfuEjcbJSGr1EWBlabw6vMmsNBKY00C4HU2OGjVa1p15jVoMtwRquUY6DMbUWpSk1IEToXX1erSckWSU9LC6CValsaXSgJ8KsgS/DhBT7At@uaPIC@gkxtHzUdr9wDalS5glE5Fydn8LWwgFlfnM5TZ72bj3nhEpdqMJ07CojN/v1DFVNrIykFdIrY34rr0J9XRbilarn8Lnj1zPsbtoFvXgmZG91IpqE@lK9UTIBtZM2jqVj0GsfWsXSp53Wag/UmNOfFBswJg4KaZU@12rumwmasr1cpf2qH@LeyWj9thyeqWR@WNn5tfynazUp7gC7GV/fIvEN5MlGrW/FIK63YDXwrc70gibqYlu363UIwhV6rf/NK2u82KVvcxsFQ6BjOgM237pVJXA3IfnasD6/6zZ3bJb03qvq5rBPWxtn/cztDolpr0vKfajcn@l/YI4/dU3JtA42sgHuPu6gDzgb46ZCzUtyBd0Dgh8iYgL2g2N37e3/h5o/n06Zf2RA@6ZSH@vcpC8UT8hIhfthF14@dlw@Ii4Sc5qvyDt/eDsZEyuQzrg5DL8dJIQeHGz@iJF6th@t8)

## Rundown

This program prints**74** in Archway, **73** in Morse, **72** in Fortran, **71** in what, **70** in Commercial, **69** in rk-lang, **68** in Python, **67** in C11, **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C99, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip). Now in driver also. Test outputs an error code, but this is acceptable according to challenge rules.
- Japt was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Incident was tested by WheatWizard. Now in Driver.
- Surface was [tested locally](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).
- Moorhens 2.0 and Deadfish were tested by WheatWizard
- Morse was tested using this [interpreter](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway was tested using this [interpreter](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)

## Archway

Archway is a 2D language based on brainfuck. The commands are the same as brainfuck except loops are replaced by reflectors (/ and ) these only activate if the current cell is non-zero. The instruction pointer starts in the lower left (ignoring the trailing newline) and travelling rightward. The only characters relevant to Archway in the last line are the + to increment the first cell to 1 and the first / which reflect the IP upward. The instruction pointer travels upward until it hits

```
/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-x--.
```

Which increments the first cell to 55 (ascii value of 7) then prints, decrements 3 times then prints 4.

Because the Archway interpreter requires the last character of a file to be a linefeed the last line had to be rearranged.

## Retina

I originally tried to fit Archway into the old last line and appending a newline, but this broke Retina. With some help from Martin Ender it was fixed by putting an M before the back tick in the (now) second last line. Martin said retina should continue working as long as the last non-empty line is a valid regex and it does not match 8.

## # comment languages

The last line line now not beginning with # broke many languages so we made it start with a #. We needed one at the end of the line to close Algol's comment as well.

## pip

Rearranging the last lines made pip fail so its answer of 25 was moved to the new last line and changed from being an integer to a string, the 5 at the beginning of the last line is because pip interprets # as meaning 'length of' so we use 5 as a dummy argument.

## trigger

The rearranging at the end of the program also broke trigger. Triggers answer of X222999 was moved from its previous location to be on the new last line.

## C, C++, etc

The */// comment delimiters were moved to the new last line.

## SMBF

SMBF was reading the 6 that was the second last character of the program. It has been moved to the new last line, but is now the 3rd last character of the program so the SMBF code on line 8 was changed from

```
#<]}}+<[<.>>-]>[
```

To

```
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
```

## Cubix/INTERCAL

The extra characters from the SMBF made the Cubix broken. This was fixed by changing the FAC in the INTERCAL to being DO.

## Incident

Since I don't understand incident I got some help from Wheat Wizard. They adjusted some of the code to fix the tokens.

Comment: Prints `73g` in Morse due to the `--.` you added :I Could be fixed by simply putting non-spaces around it.

Answer (score 9):

## 79. C++17, 2191 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw(([5]{} )))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f  2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}())wWW'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
<3>
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉p(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": p( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"# xi xi xi xi \++++>/ xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004443 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2274 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLd9tKcl4bJ/9gNm2Q1wBE4kWKevEhybY08Z3rkWLJds4laRkEQRIWCNAAKFKW6ZNtcrKY/WyynP8x2/yK@SM3X3WDD0mU7HuSRSgSaHRXd9erq6qroY6TDH77LUcfdhoF1/0gSlnqJSnrxv6VFxvs@TU7cPykUipLEoeKo@7Y9cM@Swce88PROGU9P/ASyXVS1mCjbBSDCizHYs/pCjCpF8WMurDhZcB85o5GrBM4A8NlgQ/YY2sH8Ek0JJjUi0exh2vCQs/rsmTkuX7Pd/lczJumXpj4UZgYzHcv2cQPAtb1AnRYIuAWMRgbJytVYjpD6kYSw8cd3UF38ZT3ABN6c5K9kRNzkiM24vTPKZ/EzmgEJKUcOwPiqT/0EuanSsI8J/GJj@iSeGGXc2u04HDEnHCVSnblO8wBvuOYj514cQryDD4uG3ixhyEdmrwfO0OmTmI/BQuImYfs1HNidh57noZZIAQvcZ0R8Lg1JSaLaIaUCDG4sGo15ejkWIHQRA/DGaVSLi6f/8vPksOMOstfVPGry3JVOvrzS3aTb1EZWGAwCHYUq47G6t9YYrZaHn5Tu2P245mEUSVwJWBmNEpNjOzEKdBblvSrkjEKVqZltTuSWFEkAdWFLNirkL0rcrrccRx7wGLJUucSJAdR2Ac3QWo8DokbIduyIAA3CrtJkXlX4FkUCglFE87f84EPkSUkEKcD9jgucV4sAs5OLANoXsbP@bxJFIw5HHomKakfeIKuNOKrHnvHeo4fUBe001AC69hLxkFKfcZhl@Q@9EOva7A5Gm7UJaBhdIXpHAzKK7BuhiurjSMFYIgh4qRS0z/@8tduv49xDl03iruZsr5j3cgdD4Gww5F1oIikrlHoBBwtwBVpdtEdE1w5gd91Upo@vM6m4EjwWSfROOiyCBPGEx8La@BcYTH2ep6bekLFo3EKHIts6FwKG@ELvQXhQ6cDwfIJ@NycbJ0dvICUXE8ojD4cp70dpo@OmJKYH9T9PXX/acsDbpqhbeRNs1@FthkbvApPymOK8@5wKU/SnnM/olUUjAZj2Ay0hMkI1iQmZroOyEnIqKSwe0XW4YzmlgiKzpfoxFNij3WwrueEcR0ROkD9dVq32QhLmc7hbquY113RMGgnlCxN7hmJIJpgYo4bGU/odEiTO30HU6UZQYeCIDEjr7lN2mUITafROh7b0Ts@pEN6AFOTCWOFRoCXSwIGownprSyKoXONUVxhopeSZH4PQh5Cb@Nr5nq0GLAqPGHnaJIxV4zEhx5FPWbppUrlO8JPY/NQ/9V09C/mozIm4u@I@ZD1vAkLnLA/dvpQ5ChEF8d1vVGarSBQkqRYI3fNIK/UM5tuJAMpf3B3bm7bMmu/MgdZHyG9zEI7pPZg1BCs1gOscubEfb4SWdePsV6C67uzA@DqzuTyRwK5hcBH@QEU5o4JSuZNPXecYrlBkScD3x1Adwm7UCxYYR3vTo@q1dlhcvTeYmpCxm48K0mGuagiNB4cQieJ3h8HVp@Gatyq4MJfrXh8ZCcZrhk4WqAIC7VSa5iOAd3LmAZvfkaRBMzf3HXzlbUILxb8BIN/JscUe5/HEBj02e@HBOKEC7e/Yhn9JFTgKvzEB9fJgZOun786IX/w3hMxDPgufNmqMY8Q0aB75qCpYS4EyXMHEdNDpmQ4qDL3p5@AlpnELi/oK0GErBngk0r84k3zgT6J2OyuQ2WN@3B8SqXImrLcLsKHBQlUKBwHAR7GIV9iqqfdQNdcL0kMLBjw1qBoBNjJBU@b3QZMB3E0Yd5MqyrrpvudAnkx7vjT/4cScQkvcQVVK2LgVT8ih3uAc0HIcsa6exCcdy@iIdl59p5TTPg@j@EbevAH0ug6HcDS6S6TnXo08oDSLUuiAE8E56pW5QGdohifIj9Ub5SnT58qe0pDKaK0j1KNSvtUKqC0z0s6LxGcQSXeo8hL1NrkPaiurcya85GnWptEO6Wo9Ys/Up3m3l65XXSadnYv0V2DM4HvALRON4yjaPU6FTVNbkxAqNHpSYL8cwjnF4R87BefPHEPAeJy4yAtJmtJsmBG@bYtlZctJRGrvjOHYJ8xul4fRcirQ/EOr/3wMiIdNYfz0oVl2JVbQ2C/c79nz08G/HIL9B5a91t472TY6fHLGoC9LAxATEF7JOILN2UUiUQRNH/CwYZRGAlUwC8/dMw3/GbAe6zD57aRvoXMcw9rvu/pu2Wz44dmx@s9BHn8/PkrDtPrdPyHgMAUwnt@XwMWjzvreIbYbHDPibNbXD8fx2mgd82U7t5//1sX3L8vm4FznSCav1wULsA0kpPee1BUWVd64Jf1Yv00DrDT@84YrkMRvBMsCuvH2mNvPOg@xBryDR4wDQLYE7AMdu6@cmNdBOOuN7@vH5Tz8HYsIHqH/lCHZm8ZFhcgHim@4dbngVHuBDRiGNr4xEHkdE2xFfW9pUQF772p04/Ca3PFsxlx5wdQncccbLn3TAfjdCyutOH8nuz8Ef0eW5AZpFU5fG4fZbcH4IHE1kO6K5YNmWr9OHAuzQ4VL3ooridVEBP7fexu5/eHwN6fjRzXMycJ3R60H@E4GXFB8tJDYIge40BcHwLxQxeeNVwWHgIEiQG//B6t40rgOgFUrywUj/I9@gqP/DtcDZzONfmzwe9XIJq1XygwHTak7hYKVpnp0XJDtswsjUYP93fdrP/u7vreIgnFB3Aj7J297zkleBZ/CBaUuivFB5XEj/Tl/i8RmkXxwDpj5Fw5iA8CJ4GupBnHvStIiF8e011yGe44cOJl6THNvYPUfA/@0DZu2XPkuxGcu1BVegj8tdoaUtx3N0ZaDkMJRn5ZdqWnzIy@RBhEnvjbo7Y0clPaPT2gRj9gnsTGhbaGK3phRA8xzY0m9HtwBQ@iK09c17ulL2ux@gHzowdcJRB83@/edb@nre/9BMYHl/Vm8XItVqkbrK3fY6@jKMbONWElw3pUPGuV@cx4ZfxinBhn7MwPouRRfmDfniTiul6Vl6Cd2HdC3SUdXi2v77YWMe7i2CG/PiBgJ@hHwdZO33RweVALxnGPrH12/1EjtzBStv1dI7UIa6LQzu4PmvhLfL@nIJQVgU33Kb5ZFNcry3csWrYZeJhM7ACo53oSj62dhY7FibdWuTB3BnMYu4OJc/2oCn7PnzzE7Lk/2aMsPg@lH0Xmu9NsPj5N98fs1b1htx8dlm/I3vCs@yINlhSzwwLU@XGWHE4W5y@5V6EbezwpNt/msxyl6sZDOJQ0ig3G4VTVKRQ0TRKdyDT1Q4DNoXgOnNKQIr2eMPiIlMNiK9lssvzNdM/as2eszuQ9mbXbYlSeEDuajnjy@o3o2sw77Xpe0XUlr7TCPWYpHNQLoB9rQZ1bcD2f3wSeS9JZ6Ax55pPKc0qrIr0KA0459YETdhFJvw19nsFwo1gkCUUmmu9a/v63bnbU0PdA5NBPnACMoMOxaOgNosm@mDeb/XA0cuiogsZAABeIHIf@4pAlEz91B@KEAf7l7fH5TpYezg7r8HBKIfQKFkKoaMLmPHVSITSBTTfyhLJmEy96zYmC0x4PQzbxu@kgMWCJQ9fj6ed5ShSYxAQWpnFEyl5kr1jXo2iSp2g@jSHbIIoueWaIMPn730RSHI0@qRCV59PzU5qVGRmMts0z0a4bjYH1fJAvXhxlICoxGaHHGBy5xlLzRL3G3IHDs/XQRH2eq6ZpRL76xeEZ04@YQmeMlLqu@j01f/jmj@@aVrv@jQ1NbDBNypZxvsk/6dt2IhfZHKQ6I71abbbQvGxVmJyfyhlZdJ7Fj28WSiVWE1OpzMU1zz0P@VEY1ztvwnPP/IAhpMiKzpjCBOsDjxofWiyael7FznTop0w/S1mFDmI9sAQlcXjG6GiT8qjUJT9lX9mAdEV3mV2x8CQYElDqflhf5gNWEzLmS68z5huXq5JRKtc5OfmLeq3BS7HXjehwp/mhNWmbyZwrrdb0J6s0BduiGODPTFo5R39@eZM3GtbXrwlMsizPlCpPmNHyzt@cvjo9Ojs/PH97BjbOBJW54ygeOksTQUowCuAxB1HAT8vAj9j3ku@bjSfcbkhPMkBVZXmH1ZhtMVioJwvDkrFV1uW8KIo2bkkWbXcaM/PR81lm6tgpl3YmWCVZNXPFuQIQ87Amx7Crc@ShODdrzBUnR2Z1EKSDIA6@QHjxtI6w260cXjB8n57B9IyMVShO6hJqPRDRKoAzvAWMQHItEbP/I8xH8CPfx5ygvoc5gKXvzb4y8fHhq1/evjm6P/fKtBnMPZCFhqy8nnA0RYwDO9jjGk6HYHO9ibJDzLlhgN0fiMy6EyxNW7JIkpMm9cgwB1jbtCh4CiGhxc3IjhjsMEhgSLtdWIbOdUqGBRZV5MUXyXE5BwYYCz9XZLJEsEn9/mEWDMcEkaj7UXTOczg@crLuPLjlmf/4y1/FGXArRfnfs3IP5f8U5Q8mMej@oaHAccEaYsu7V6csgbcShA@d6QpN5DDIIfnhGMHYEBy84gwhcIHskt7lOGrzHfgJIYCZZPnI2PH5vLitDtJ0tGea5N8R2PcMnlj0ppADbKWBUNj8PKYjedhnc6uytWmbQFK/mg/IT3r6lOUSA2raHlRIuvJH9Y8dl9VqNSYnrhN49a2qYKSZdz6U5Y8LRPOAlUQo0GTogy7LHmhrZN3UvFOwNepKq1CxFdauwssLucBRqLwAEI2qw4wfMjxRlLGKDo28acqN6vU8xEF8EUZsSHziL2bMB9IxkBhbk6V7ugt80cJTWf6t2NJYFYP8nsB44mtPXqc6DBryX2s0J0T5P0S52bL0b@11LxUsdOfw/rsD6t2Tf6KFHZyFEWU3j4ErU0tmqWzaW9rKOpGzoYAtrYqvGBLrAOvK9fxP0Sg5fHH06ueT07N7Z98cUrkLpjClUSu0dKPYbC8Kyh2dn7P0@bF59vr58ZyRq1hlTXexWjf4XcQemOy9yB3en4o33JvItn504GX6Yi0hy@TGCuALkde4N6uq3cya7VqjFebuTf913YspOWOD3kVBqZXw11IUtsbAvJpnRM@jS6jHIyfuekoQ/pfVs/d5PpUOtksNs@tdmXQSKxnLTKucV2u3sNXE2wGCB/PpYSeymrwtY97lXK50L0m1iojIE0QLTG71XDCbaD4ROzv@co0TIqiPfVdAJ9y4iv0ffxMEO4BX6XLTgI0IFpTP90bXfB@AZb5I@nR9ng904uuMgkXLmTf09fM5PrTol8edMELY@GP7kQwCv1N16s0pWxwGPnYSaiSjwE9VOoKcGrS/AjWqRgTYtcCjE8zabjs7LmXzU80CPxg9HYNfp9GILfe0L7156Q22NezlGINDAzz283gIuB6/vfHIwnvsz5GOzuCjMkeiiVnUjAZj2K1gdmPgTbt@H15C1YowKD/Z9vJI1dEK2IsqsKGCVX@kTNYqY37XMfAKx5ymY/hh15uqykTR9trEHdQrk/dXiibf0wF@Fp0dTHfvHkrP176TZotwcaC7unDmAQsmz46D4EToVUF6CQAbBR86ffAnLwyhMirQHkJBmDMGnbFWnL@vWly8XbRiF/45O1266yWOlJsggi/Mm1W@JanO4BA@tlgrbfVaIXmF6rX5B9MwqzdqPqhfm3DkWkPND@p2obxRKOTDDTUfkit79ox2MrM8POWFIRvyFEB6PtCq4Cc8az0fVvNOTc1366UN3gOPhYJ2gw7fEtO4yTszM/8MjqmImlhoh5pPNBKHZRj2DPiRhPJmceiMblSZyVN6SYumz/uFAuFg5C8IgW9m66zAzVTrzOR7p2oWIJn94VyNbynDb7/l7C3E6jM1KuyXyk8PdCabG62XV1Wl6fRKxuf26eXp6b9qLVXJvTiR7U25umFKOXPD@rptmh8/fkTMwLSmrrSbamN7e6Na3NrZKB4UbaVYzbHAtmxbU0slrbUZnrEn1SdPnqj2qaJUysrZB3qzYP8p/vgXn8UjXZ/ymqyag9z/PNWY@nkq5RpPoCflracHTz5KOSl30SjgY/BrobC3d6Dr@hQ/o7Av5T7WAFNrz2aFWrNWMxqNaUNvN5pS7kbKTWdSriQTAzakXH1ae8MHaL7MRip8/gWXmt5ujk5/OTo8OyqWanqudHz4olg6e/s8Z@OpsnykxjI9vjk6fHny9rxYEr3@@Ord0dtT1Pu@P0q63WTzZOvkoBsN2o2Dg4IBRA@MRhsYTX8qNAr1NE3ZrxcbhhNLuZeN6VtTrwGLX6TcGw6rtzRAf5VyzVxT3S/tl6zAurLsS/vydXSy/J6coN6fWp@i2BpYA7tr2/bU8t5a19b11BpGJ3YXRQ9/1hBF3@pNrb4VWqFt3xrn4e/wJHp9EmGoCN3SqZXSqFYP9/7JyWsM1sPEn/DnWxbhN7Wu8LUCm38@XFiaJWFD2K5sjUpbn5vctFR2201v6qdtmRWVVlNpV3Nm0mqZQpflEtSRmmezi4uXh@eHFxcm7ZCmtXzhoKAf4FNvFGrZbT/XbRDHjJqkqJP379/T7/3kaiJKvCDq3i8aVx94AZ@rB/reLqhqs9K@mWFLqD1pKVVFYKyqHnyiKtutaanHWEnmvmYXK90uI55Xtypao7FVwfPWjqarFrVuah/sWi1rKmlRLCtTOYoVdjMTf@rNrKbyj0Z/mkaV2bWh3ag1gACmovFn0QFgQFPJzXJkTkO2WdEQnHva5pa6U9jN/upPNQwql5UyBpWVnDTnct3OERJSzqi@ke2SrBDXq5RoigLPCBACl3clGR9JQYylVGmHBkOoZjmeVmtqWTAb1U49f5NzZlVJkmeyAMs@RI1S5Tk/@UbOO3HTbgMmf9OZkZPAZ8PWuIWvbFarG5uivL1TraJhI2ux0JIV0eAljsu1BYaJDw@iNKne8fp@KNXKDanWuJHg0joIUyZs20LIEgROzKJe76nk@KIJ7hn7GmztEy8IaINI0ekkioPuBBETwWGvHjOH/kcC6zVJPHyGp4439rzJeDzxFp8XfrLnfPqEIIwMKlysJRnkDkul3Z3Kzm65tFPc2d3ZrNhblUrRLhXt7Z3tXasIi7pjb@1Udu3izuZueXNzcxetld1tKeeFXb9nmjBdtiwzXkAgR29@1OgdmcgYNJiU63o9yhA@Gald7Umuu6gY7zC5vNOyWpYs0TtRTIWEbmgVqixByBX1VKs4hlZW9sc78ta2vLeBu7wvl1FkI5VZCmQqKy1Z1pq77X15u4Kh9mDkdeWZvc/k7V15T97eRqVWnQG7OdULvBnWpmEw/HRdonbhsFR5G@tEqQKsKrr800qf@HIP@@qYgnsOjth3a1emaoDUGpXOxl7R1osHYjC2ZUu5mdSlM@XN3SoZ/VmtIeUVolgpSzm9HG1GuXw@Dx9x3pDL8olRMzPr3zC59W@RNyDLa0h1zEF6npNzbOovvy0Bfqvuf/@NEsI9l3yNKva38Odqbm@klDeVcqueE8bF3tZyjdK2kTjXubaoY@rmtsbwxJdByc71JvyzMGr3TNxKac3z5GrInSHQ2PlDt9/3S394/fErNkSKgjVpb33Ta@Jbw@XFicBL3qrIGtZCkny4@HABB11hcqkiM1YwGbZV5r@WoPS7u1s7WznpN9N8bEOF1kU82PMQKo2H6wLCw9h/7VAGK1wEhSi8HmPnsFgUjFYFhdqDxu06vlJuVfF/oUGdRHiRqqhUcOK@W@RpNbZBrz412xq7madkVWqlrKC2SCLGXjqOQ2ZVRbKXhvCriyJmoWXG6gTAc37wAqpft6vMr9FguCNszGagz7xHoU5F2q5wLPy2VpVWs6MckwZ6r@Cy0r9QEOAzgZagxx12BdmibfEI9IZ0iuSqWW/tDkDTagNGaVlKRuaPkIF9gboYoch@Nxl3@iNC1uY0cRSWjVn9UhQzaSMtDqsSkb0xqkp/Ul3thiL36rfhs2fuh1Fz2K5qw3pK90JhWJ1Jl6ovQDbS@rCu29URkK2mzULBb9eH2p/UEUd@WLcAjLlp5ES7WUg6rGfiSrTil2aofwvbxeNmWLDbxXFx49f6l6JTt4pT/MC2YlD8DObNWamm9S@FsOrU8KNNxC1OjOpJwaneTlqjy6Ua1L80nXbd0qoBOhYKxyAGeCbNoFBoa5g8QOP9jtXg2TOnEDSm1UDXNYL6UN4/bqYotAt1et5Tndp0/0tzjP57Ku51TBNoQB79bssA4wG/KngsxLdEXeA4JfSmQG9Yr2/8ur/x60b96dMvzak@bBcF@/espeAJ@Skhv6oj6savq4rFWcIjDlX@yd/7ydhImFyE9oHJxdFKT4Hhxq9oGS1Xw@x/AA)

Languages that are not on TIO:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use python 2. Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse (#73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway (#74) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98 (#76) [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Note that flags must be `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98. Could also be installed via pip.

Languages that use abstracted interpreters in the test driver:

- V (#2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)
- Alphuck (#44) [local](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master)
- What (#71) [local](https://github.com/gimmetehcodez/what/blob/master/what.c)

Other languages:

- Japt (#7) was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).

### Explanation

#### Adding C++17

[C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) standard is not published yet (will be published this year), but it is unlikely to change so late in the standardization process.
[Isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/std/status) states: "The committee has completed work on C++17, which is now in its final ISO balloting process..."

[Trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) are optional in the new standard, see [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) par C.4.1 page 1453
"Change: Removal of trigraph support as a required feature."
Gcc does not support trigraphs by default in C++17 mode.
So to separate C++17 from C++14 we can just use `'??-'&1`:

```c++
puts( '??-'&1 ? "C++17" : "C++14" );
```

#### Incident

Incident broke as a result. Added `\0` to untokenize `5"` and `7"`. Changed `_` to `\0` in `u8` to untokenize `\0`.

Answer (score 9):

## 85. zkl, 2379 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#~
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<\>@*99[?]*]*.*|!)'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>{\';   a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};

" }"';           (( ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main ( ␉){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003873 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2463 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbdtpKls/Rmj/ol7LEiSRANzC@IMD2SZyenD459sRO0usAcYQoQLEuRBIGh5A1rzNrHvq9X@ax/6Nf5yv6R87sXSUBNtjJWTOz1oCRSlW7qvat9t61S@45yei33yT8kPPIvx36UUpSmqSkH3s3NNbJj7fk2PGSWqUqCAwqjvoT1wuHJB1R4oXjSUoGnk8TwXVS0iLjbBQdC0QiMXX6HEwYRDHBLiS49olH3PGY9HxnpLvE9wD2hXkA8EkUIExK43FM4ZqQkNI@ScbU9Qaey@YidJbSMPGiMNGJ516Tqef7pE996LBCwC3DYGSSrFXx6XShHwkEPu74HrrLpwIFmJDmJNOxEzOSIzJm9OeUT2NnPAYkBYlcAOKpF9CEeKmcEOokHvIRuiQ07DNujZccjogTrlNJbjyHOIDvJGZjJzROgTydjUtGNKYwpIOTD2MnIMo09lJgATLzhJxTJyaXMaUqzAJCoInrjAGPO1PCZBHOkCIhOhNWoyGfnr2QQWi8h@6MU0GKq5f/8pPgEL1JClc2/JqiaAunvzwn80IHy4AFDAaCHceKo5LmV5IYnQ6F38zqGcN4IcCoAnDFJ0Y0Tg1HGwOCWgoIGg4WsaTdVPSxvzYxadyTxZoqcag@SIO8DMnbMqPMncQxBTxWTHWugWg/CofATyA2noTIj5DsmSACNwr7SZnQG@BaFHIZRVPG4cuRB0JLUCRODxjkuMh7vgwYQ2EhgO5lHM3nTSJ/wuCgZ5KiAgJXoCuO@HJA3pKB4/nYBdpxKI51TJOJn2KfSdhHyQdeSPs6ydFwoz4CBdENTOfAoKwCVk6wtt4YUgAMgogYqdj0j7/8tT8cwjgnrhvF/Uxd35J@5E4CQNhhyDqgiqiwUej4DC2AK@PsvDtMcOP4Xt9JcfrwNpuCIcFmnUYTv08imDCeerC0Rs4NLMfBgLop5UoeTVLAsUwC55pbCY9rLhAeOD0QLJuAzc3I1sjxM5CSS7nKaMEkHRwQbXxK5MR4rxzVlaOdDgXcVF0tFgxjaIO@6UVWBU/yY4rz9mQlT9SeSy/CdeSPRxOwGtASJmOwJzEy03WAnATNSgqWr0x6jNHMFoGqs0U6pXJMSQ9Wdk4Y0xGuA9hfw5WbjbCSaQ53V8Vof03DQDtBydJkw0z40RQmZrih@QSdDnFyZ@jAVGlG0AkniM/Iau6Sdh2CpuNoPUoOtJ4H0kE9AGOTCWONRgCvVjgMjMalt7YoAucWRnG5kV5JkngDEHIAehvfEpfiYoBVQbmlw0kmTDESD/QoGhBTq9Rq3xB@Ghsn2q9gPT4bj8oYib8n5hMyoFPiO@Fw4gxBkaMQujiuS8dptoKAkiSFNXLfELJKLbPqejISCsf352bWLbP3a3Og9eHSy2y0g2oPjAqA1ZoPq5w48ZCtRNL3Ylgv/u392QHg5t7k4gcEuYPAB/EBFHLXBEpGZ9SdpLDcQJGnI88dge4idiFfsNw63p8eqtZnB5OjDZZTIzJW62lF0I1lFaLx4BAaSnRzHLD6OFTrTgUT/nrF4yM7SbBl4GiJIliotVrdcHTQvYxp4M8vMJYA85c7b7aylgHGkp/A4J/QMcX00wQEBvrsDUMEccKl41@zjF4SyuAqvMQDrqMLR12/fHmG/uAd5VEM8J37snVjHkFMA90zF40NuRAE6o4iooVEznBQROZRPwJaRhK7rKCthRGiqgOfFOQXa8oH@sijs/sOlbQ24diUcpm0RbFbBh/mJ6BC4cT34WESsiWmUHUOuubSJNFhwQBvdYxHADuxRNXFXcB0FEdTQheqLW@b7ncK5Nmk583@H0rERbz4FahaEwOr@h45bADmghDFjHUbEIx3z6IA7Tx5xyhGfH@MwTcMwB8I49t0BJZOc4noNKMxBZTuWBIZ8ITwXFFtFtLJsv4x8kJlLu/s7Mh1uSWXoXQEpQaWjrBUgtIRK2mshHA6lliPMitha5v1wLquvGjnI8/ULop2hnHrZ2@sOO16vdotO20ru1fwroIzAd8B0BreYBxZbTaxqKpiawqE6r2BwMm/BOH8DCEf@dlDTzyAAHG1dRCWk3UEkTOjeteWiquWCo9Wb4wA2KePb7dHEeL6UKwDBHDXEeroqnRl6lbtzhCw49nsOfCSEbvcAd1Aa7OF9U6C3oBdtgDUszAAYgrcJSFfmCnDSCSKQPOnDCyIwoijAvzyQsd4zW46eI9t@Nw10neQ6VFY80Nq9LwQy98A0w4PGOSg1/MeAgW@IOr5fQtYPOltYxuEZ6MNP07uMD6dxKlP@9n9v/61DwLYFM/IuU0goL9eFq6AbygqbfCgtLKu@MAu2yX7ceLDdu8bY7gOBvGOvyxsH6tOXlNQf5BsyHZ5gKkPtGGEA6ZuU79hafiTPs3v2wdlPLwbDvDeoRcwycEdYxtmeR7ofi@Y4f1x0xP7kdM3@EbUoytRcqbTmTOMwltjzavpce87cMzjDbLaeaajSTrhV9xsfkto3hh/jy3GDNKsOT2LGlHi9LwHOIhI7D2ktHwtoJnWBr5zzYtXWNxOKicm9oaws83vD4FBtAcB@dhxqTFltwftRzhJxkyYrPTIeLHPrw@BeKELnjVcFR4CBDJ9dvk9KscUwYV1gKhiskdbY5F3j6m@07tFVzb6/fqDEw5LJaKB7Wi6pZJZJVq02out0krj8cP9XTfrf3i4vTfPQLEB3Ai2zfRb/gicihc4vlbprxUftK@561@Vtpkf58aBoMB3ElCQNGMzvQGxsMtjSot@wp34TrwqPaKyK3TyLfdDu7ZVn7HnRr6XaWb@sGWCEMO8@yHRahjMKLLLqis@ZSbzOUQ96Hi/Pmo3IzfFzdIDqvMdFonvU3AnuKYLevQQu9xoir8HF@wouqH8ut0Ffd6K1XdYHM1nygCx9mb3vvstDcU8ELtst4TXW7FKXX9rfZ28iqIYNqoJqejmo@LZqsaJ50cJuWDXx3gBW/Qk4dftCrzONs8JNXfEl9WyvL3bVqSYRyMn7PqAcB1/GPl7B0PDgcuDGjCJB2jYs/v3GrWlUbKsbxqlZfgShVZ2f9CaX8Pft5QDEyBgvj2MY5bF7YryoAXLIv6HCYQwHxNe24l7YR4sNStO6KMqVScnsTuaOrePQn3LczzE5txz1DFZzwLh/9k0u49P0/8@K7Ux7P7jw94R77VPwUyz64ZQScW0fmcPyzS/32YN/Amd0K025Kz3kYLifHdQ/ChSZkZGnXy@9h8bk21IX7NTh2UaMClnxyVQ58VZcjxZnkBJL0M3piwpmKc5iISpykkAvjWNYp0wOEVxSiVVFXgntNXDEMByKHYGgGlYfryQEHCaKYOFrXS7TQrzWd2sWwvSJGJdJN0uH5UlBE9nY5a8f827tgtOt1mQNU0uyJ2wTkyZgVIfls5WUOcO3MBjN47ninQSOgHL/GI5p9Tm6WXwaHimMHLCPuwm3oQey@C4UcyTpDwTf4lbtb//rZ8dtQwpEBl4ieMDI/B4MAroKJoe8Xmz2U/GYwePanAMCGB9nuPRnp2QZOql7oifsIDDffPi8iBLj2fHlfBwjtuINSy4UKFpADg4KRcax6YfUa4V2cTLXjlREMVMgpBMvX46SnRwT6FLWfo9TwkDJjGChWkcoVaVyUvSpxhNsxTVxwnI1o@ia5YZQ0z@/jd@KACNHqoQlvPp2SnV2owEFpPFMvGuG00A63yQzzSOMhAFmQyx2AQ4cgs6TXm9StyRw04rQBO1PFeP0/B8/bOTC6KdEhlPWTF1b3sDpXDy@o9v22a3@ZUEBuyuDcwWMr6JP2j7ViKWSQ5iL1Cv1ptNaF61ykQszMSMLDzPY8dXS6Xiq4koWGbiynPvATsKZHpHpyz3zg5YQgw18YwtTGB9wKPKhuaLpllQYFseeCnRLlJSw6NoCiyBEj88JHi4i3lk7FKYkS9khLqiucSqmfDEGeLj0UXQ/DFPdFTXE1LGc9qbsM3bTUWvVJuMnMJVs9FipZj2Izzcar/vTLtGknOl05n9YFZmwLYoBvCnBq6c01@ezwt6y/zyJQFvJYoL2WYJQ1zehfn5y/PTi8uTyzcXwMYFp1J6EcWBszIRqARjH8KIUeSz00LgR@zR5Ntm4wmzG8KTDFBRSMEhDTDeBCzUk6VhydgqamKBF3kbsyTLtnuNmfkYeCQzdeScSTsTrJysm7lyrgDIPFiTE7CrOfKgOPMt5oqRI5ImEKQBQQx8ifDyaRthd1sZPGf4ET4D0zMy1qEYqSuo7UBIKwfO8OYwHMmtRCz@lzAfgx/5NuYI9S3MAVj41uxrE784efnzm9enm3OvTZvBbIAsNWTtBY3TGYR/YAcHTMPxEDDXmyg7xM0NA9j9ET9ZcPyVaUuWhwSoSQM0zD6sbVwULIWS4OImaEd0cuInYEj7fbAMvdsUDQtYVH4usDwcECVggL70c2UiCgibNDcP88BwTCE8dz/wzgUGx0ZOtp2Hd6jxj7/8lZ@Bd1Io/1tWHkD5P3j5vYEM2jw05TguWYNsefvynCTgrTjhgTNbowkdBjokL4QgywuAgzeMIQjOkV3RuxpHab8FfoIQgJlo@dDYsflo3FVGaTquGwb6d9jtDHSWVaUzkAPYSh32B8anCb6SAPbZ2Kvt7VoGIKnd5AOyk64hZvr4gKpaBxUSbrxx80PPJY1Gg4iJ6/i0uWdzRhoF531V/LBEtACwAg8F2gT6QJdVD2hrZd2UglOyVOyKq1C2ZNK1wctzuYCjUFgBQFSsDjN@iOCJooxVeGhGZykzqrd5iAPxRRiRAPnEXkzJB9JgID62KgoburvK6OFJxpo26@tiEN8h2AWC1cVtqkNAQ/5zi@aEUP53Xm53TO1rd9tLFUvdOdl8d0K5/@YD0kKOL8IIM7wvAFeiVIxK1bD21LV1ImZDAba4Kr7AkLAOYF251PsYjZOTZ6cvfzo7v9g4@2eQ8n0wmcitRqmj6eV2d1mQ7@l8ztIfXxgXr358kTNyHaus6T5W2wa/j9gDk73judPNqVjDxkSW@b0Ds4M@7QVsiLYSsmw11gCf8UTPxqyKOl@0u41WJ5Q2pv@y7cUcSS/iuzhQ6iTstRyZbDEwL/OM8GV0DerxyBsHWooQ3uf1dw/yfDIe7FdaRp/eGHgSLeirTLNYUBp3sFX52xGcB/n0YCeymgLs5VpkNZcrbGTt1hHhyZNoicmdnktmI81nfGfHXi5yQgjqY8/l0Akzrnz/x96EgR3Ay3S1aYCNCO5V2d7olu0DYJkvs2B9jyVInfg2o2DZckEDT7vM8cFFvzruBSMUxSlsP5KR7/Vsp9mekeVh6GMnwXoy9r1UwSPYmY77K6BGUZEAq@FTPMFtHHaz42KSn@qW2MHw@QT4dR6NyWpP@5zmpdewrSHPJzA4aAAlP00CgBuw22uKFp6SXyINOgMf5RyJNsyiZDToQb8Gs@sjOut7Q/ASiloGg/KDZa2OlB21BHtRGWwoZ9UfMb23zpjfdQy@xjGn7ehe2KczRZ7Kar2L3IF6efruRlbFDR1gZ/HZwXz//qF8vvadNFuEywPt9YWTBywweXYkBk4EX5XElyBgo@CBTh//iYYhqIwCaAegIMSZAJ2xWs7f2C0v365aswv/nJ2w3fcSp/Lcj8AXFgybbUnsBTiEDx3SSTuDTohewb41/mDohj1XCn7z1gBHrraUwqhplarFUqkQFpVCiK7s6VPcySwK4CmvdFEXZwCkFXzVBn6CZ20WQrvgNJRCv1kpsh7wWCqpc@jwNTH0ecFZGIWn4JjKUBNz7VAKiYriMHXdWgB@KKGCUQ6c8VwRiTjDl9Rw@oJXKiEOeuEKEfhqdC5KzEx1Lgy2d7KzAMkYBrka31GG336TrD2I1RdKVDqqVHeONSIaxc7zG1tuO4OK/ql7fn1@/me1o8jSszPR2hXtoiFIRtH8sm8YHz58gJiBqG1N7raV1v5@0S7vHRTLx2VLLtsS8S3TslSlUlE7u@EFeWI/efJEsc5luVaVL97jmxVHO/Blf/BZPuJ1h9Vk1Qxk87OjEuXTTJBaT0BPqns7x08@CNJXQbpqleCjs2upVK8fa5o2g59eOhKkDw0AglBIarW6i0Wp0W409FZr1tK6rbYgzQVpthCkiohsKApSc9Z4zUZpP8@GK336GS4Nrdsen/98enJxWq40NKny4uRZuXLx5kfJgqfa6hEbq/j4@vTk@dmby3KF9/rjy7enb86h3vO8cdLvJ/1o1G0dH5d0QPRYb3UBmdkPpVapmaYp@fWqqDvx7tne2bEgPW/N3hhaA7D4WZBesw5aR4UuXwSpLbWVo8pRxfTNG9O6tq5fRWerv7MzqPdm5scoNkfmyOpbljUz6Rvz1rydmUF0ZvWhSOFrBlD0zMHMHJqhGVrWnXEe/gvOoldnEQwVQbd0ZqY4qjmA@/Ds7BUMNoCJP8LXM03Eb2bewJ/pW@zz/spUTQG2hd3a3riy96nNDEztsNumMy/tiqQsd9py15aMpNMxuEaLFVBKbF4srq6en1yeXF0ZuE@aNQql45J2DJ9mq9TIbkdSv4Uc0xuCrEzfvXuHv3fTmykvsQKve7dsXH9gBfjcPND3bkFR9OLm98A61EtQKB23a935QiXwfdKRbZkTpCgUHKciWp1ZZUAqIvNHh2ANrCrE/MpeTW219mrwvHegaoqJrbvqe6vRyJoqahSL8kyMYpnMF/yrzBcNhX1U/KoqVmbXlqpAs1qDp9lcmTWUhoJ1UIW95osWFhncgpfgCkMAgRjf/x/9RQlsRoksLSS09yHZramwe6Dq7p5yUDrMvs0dQF0Rq3IVKBJlR263j4vV4v5u@6hb7BaVRqd1XDw85E968cuOKktCriRNS0IuCZJuvxatiiij0tiYLYt8qvsQx1cPBRE@gtxozUE8YEbBmitZoqrTmZkmbj1Vu9cszCVnYQuCSBYiA8w/ikLgK9sseynOxYITt62uuBAL894C3V3RUpmjqu3adnGXl/cPbBsailmLCS1ZERpo4rhM3cG@ojxlIF0Vmj069EIBPHIPuDcl@yZEXL7vxCQaDHZ4PYQWsCej4Fqp7@PmFiPraRT7/SlEezuClFD4BOcOnVA6nUymdPl55iV15@NHiBjHaP4hIDAFHZ13pXJ4UDs4rFYOygeHB7s1a69WK1uVsrV/sH9olsH@H1h7B7VDq3ywe1jd3d09hNba4b4g0bDvDQwDTKwlioQVIOzEl3Qa@DpTpI9aRJD6dID5zCe@0lefSP1lxeSAiNWDjtkxRQHfYAMuP1HnaC0UkkCAGA2IYpYnsEBqR5MDcW9frBfhLh6JVSj6CjFlEJ4od0RRbR92j8T9GgxVB5ekyU@tIyLuH4p1cX8fKlV7AdjlVC/xJmBDdJ3AT9MEbOfuVRH3YcXKNoDZvMs/rfWJr@tJ6sS4FWHgEKnvHYpYDSCNVq1XrJctrXzMByN7liAthD6@ErB7aKNzWjRaQkFGiuWqIGnVaDeSCoUCOLTLllgVz/SGkXmplsG8VAe9FnoIPXd6LSGmmP7s43@3cINzUFNtrEyEJtQLNii9JEq3s9Wnw4dsfJXYYS85n2NWKnvxtf4K8FGc@gV7yandJerXXzx/flDVWizEg1BzQRZIipR8iWrW1/AnW6qP5equXO00JY6Dta9Krcq@nji3UpfXEWV3XyXwxJS/YkmDKfssbfGGZV4rbXme3gTMhwMaB3/oD4de5Q@vPnyB3ZwsAzXW3letwf8acHl2xvES92qiKiVJ8v7q/ZUkSDUiVmoiISWDwJbQ@HMFlsDh4d7BniT8ZhiPbQahdRnLDiiEeZNgWzB7EnuvHMy@hcuAFgqvJrDrWS4RgmsEtwmj1t06tm7uVLF/gII6AfFCxVGw4MRDt8xSgqSIr661uyqZ5@lkBVsxo6kuE6AxTSdxSEybJ6pxCM9eFmEWXHSkiQAsXwneSfGalk28Bg4Gdwh5sxnwk/coNbGIWy2GhddVbWE9s8swaUHvNVzW@pdKHHzB0eL0uEGfk83blo@AXoAnYK6S9VbvAbTNLsDIHVPOyPweMmBPoyxHKJPfTca9/hDdqzlNDIVVY1a/EsVCKKblwBaQ7OLYFv6kuOocdx321@DpU/f9uB10bTVopngvlQJ7IVwrHgcpps2gqVn2GJC103ap5HWbgfonZcyQD5omAMPcOHKizpeSDpuZuBK1/Lkdal/DbvlFOyxZ3fKkXPy1@bnsNM3yDH7AtrJf/gTMy1mppM3PpdB2GvDDDdAdToybScmx7ybcocu14jc/t51u01RtHzqWSi@AGMAzafulUleFyX1o3Oxo@0@fOiW/NbN9TVMR6n316EU7hUK31MTnuuI0Zkef2xPoX1fg3oRpfBWQh353ZQDjAX428JiLb4U6x3GG6M0AvaDZLP56VPy12NzZ@dyeaUG3zNlfN1eCR@RniPy6jijFX9cVi7GEBRqK@INX/0EvJkQsg/YBk8vjtZ4cw@Kv0DJerYbFfwM)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)

### Explanation

zkl is a dynamically typed language that feels somewhat like lua or ruby (I think, I have never programmed in either of those). The main feature of the language with regards to the polyglot is the variety of comment syntax:

- `//` line comment
- `#` line comment
- `/* */` block comment, can be nested
- `#if 0 #endif` block comment
- `#<<<# #<<<#` block comment, insides unparsed

Though the only kinds of comments used in this program are `#` comments and `#<<<#` comments.

The line that was previously

```
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
```

Is now

```
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
```

This opens a block comment. The extra > are to keep perl6 and brainfuck balanced. This block comment extends until just before the end of the ruby block comment.

```
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
```

The block comment ending has some perl6 balancing > tacked on the end. The code that actually does the printing is the `print(85)`. The `reg`s are variable declarations (`var` could be used instead). `reg s` is used to make the `=end` part of an assignment. The `reg end=""` is used to give end a value. A semicolon was added to the start of the next line to separate statements. zkl is okay with the adjacent string literals. An x was deleted from the string of x to keep archway aligned.

### Cubix, Incident, Prelude

Standard adjustements made for Cubix and Prelude.

One of the spaces inside the brackets for the C main method is now a tab to detokenise `)`.

### Going forward

The Archway code could be put inside the currently empty string literal in the zkl code.

The zkl code could be moved higher if we introduce another block comment for the code after it.

Comment: Hmmm... does this work in whitespace? I tried to compile it and it didn't print anything.

Comment: @bearacuda13 according to the test driver in the TIO link it does work, it should be printing 30. Are you copying from the post or the TIO link?

Comment: I was using a different one, tutorialspoint or whatever... +1!

Answer (score 9):

## 92. C89, 2697 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.xxxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppp
More 91 of thisof re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof( "(\"           ); print'(''72'')';end!"           ); main( ){puts("92" );return 0;}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003463 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2785 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvLdts4luvwzB/0BiZVISmJL8myZb1sV2J3p7rS9sROMieS4lAUJDHmQ0VSlhxFOb2dObPofW9m2f/R2/6K/pGaewFSki3ZTp2ZOWdomwSJC@C@cB8A3LPj0a@/SniR89C7HXphQhIaJ6QfuTc00smPt@TIduNKqSwIDCoK@xPHDYYkGVHiBuNJQgauR2PBsRPSIuO0Fx0LRCIRtfscTBiEEcEmxL/2iEuc8Zj0PHukO8RzAfbUrAJ8HPoIk9BoHFG4xySgtE/iMXXcgeuwsQidJTSI3TCIdeI612Tqeh7pUw8arBBwitAZmcRrn/hwutAPBQKXM76H7vItRwEmoBnJdGxHjOSQjBn9GeXTyB6PAUlBIheAeOL6NCZuIseE2rGLfIQmMQ36jFvjJYdDYgfrVJIb1yY24DuJWN8xjRIgT2f9khGNKHRp4@DDyPaJMo3cBFiAzDwm59SOyGVEqQqjgBBo7NhjwOPOkDBYiCMkSIjOhNVoyCdnpzIIjbfQ7XEiSFH58l9/EmyiN0nuqg5/TVGsCyd/eknmuQ6WAQvoDAQ7jhRbJc1vJDY6HQp/M6tnDKOFAL0KwBWPGOE4MWxtDAhqCSBo2FjEknZT0sfe2sCkcU8Wa6rEofogDfIqIO@KjDJnEkUU8Fgx1b4Gor0wGAI/gdhoEiA/ArJnggicMOjHRUJvgGthwGUUThmHL0cuCC1Gkdg9YJDtIO/5NGAMhYkAupdyNBs3Dr0Jg4OWcYIKCFyBptjjqwF5Rwa262ETqMeuONYRjSdegm0mQR8l77sB7eskQ8MJ@wjkhzcwnA2dsg8wc/y1@caQAmAQRMhIxap//uWv/eEQ@jl2nDDqp@r6jvRDZ@IDwjZD1gZVRIUNA9tjaAFcEUfnzWGAG9tz@3aCwwe36RAMCTbqNJx4fRLCgNHUhak1sm9gOg4G1EkoV/JwkgCOReLb19xKuFxzgXDf7oFg2QBsbEa2Ro5egJQcylVG8yfJoEq08QmRY@OjclhTDnc6FHBTdTWfM4xhHfRNz7NP8CY/pjjvjlfyRO25dEOcR954NAGrATVBPAZ7EiEzHRvIidGsJGD5iqTHGM1sEag6m6RTKkeU9GBmZ4QxHeE6gO01nLlpDyuZZnB3VYz21zQMtBOULIk3zIQXTmFghhuaT9DpAAe3hzYMlaQEHXOC@Ijsy13SrgPQdOytR0lV67kgHdQDMDapMNZoBPByicNAb1x6a5PCt2@hF4cb6ZUkiTsAIfugt9EtcShOBpgVlFs6HGTCFCN2QY/CATG1UqXyhPCTyDjWPoD1@GI8KmMk/p6Yj8mATolnB8OJPQRFDgNoYjsOHSfpDAJK4gTmyH1DyD5qqVXX45GQO7o/NrNuqb1fGwOtD5deaqNtVHtglA@s1jyY5cSOhmwmkr4bwXzxbu@PDgA39wYXPyHIHQQ@iQ@gkLkmUDI6o84kgekGijwduc4IdBexC/iE5dbx/vDwaX10MDnaYDk0ImO1npcE3Vh@QjQe7EJDiW72A1Yfu2rd@cCEv/7h8Z7t2N/ScbhEESzU2lfdsHXQvZRp4M8vMJYA85c5bzazlgHGkp/A4J/QMUX0lwkIDPTZHQYIYgdLx79mGd04kMFVuLELXEcXjrp@@eoM/cF7yqMY4Dv3ZevGPISYBpqnLhorMiEI1BmFRAuInOKgiMyjfga0jDhyWEFbCyNEVQc@KcgvVpV19JlHZ/cdKmltwrEh5SJpi2K3CD7Mi0GFgonnwcskYFNMoeocdM2hcazDhAHe6hiPAHZigaqLu4DJKAqnhC7UurxtuN8okBeTnjv7fygRB/Hid6BqTQzs0/fIYQMwE4QopqzbgGC8exH6aOfJe0Yx4vtjBL5hAP5AGN8mI7B0mkNEuxmOKaB0x5LIgCeE54paZyGdLOufQzdQ5vLOzo5ck1tyEUqHUGpg6RBLBSgdspLGSginY4m1KLIS1rZZC/zWlRftrOeZ2kXRzjBu/eKOFbtdq5W7Rbttpc8SPlVwJuA7AFrDB/Qjq80mFlVVbE2BUL03EDj5lyCcnyHkIz@76IkHECCuUgdhOVhHEDkzyndtqbiqKfFo9cbwgX36@HZ7FCGud8UaQAB3HaKOrkpXpm5V7nQBGc9my4Ebj9jtDugGWps1rHXs9wbstgWgloYBEFNgloR8YaYMI5EwBM2fMjA/DEKOCvDLDWzjDXvo4D224XPXSN9Bpkdhzg@p0XMDLD8Bph1UGeSg13MfAgW@IOrZcwtYNOltYxuEZ6MNP07uMD6ZRIlH@@nzH3/ugwA2xTOyb2MI6K@XhSvgG4pKGzworbQpvrDbdsl@nniQ7j3Rh2NjEG97y8L2vmrkDQX1B8kGLMsDTD2gDSMcMHWb@g1Tw5v0afbc3inj4d1wgLcOXJ9JDp4Y2zDL80Dze8EMb49JT@SFdt/giahLV6LkTKczexgGt8aaV9Oj3nfgmMUbZJV5JqNJMuF3TDafEpo7xr/HJmMKaVbsnkWNMLZ77gMcRCT2HlJaPhfQTGsDz77mxSssbieVExO5Q8hss@dDYBDtQUA@th1qTNnjQfsRTOIxEyYrPdJf5PH7QyBu4IBnDVaFhwCBTI/dfovKMUVwYB4gqrjYo62xyL3HVM/u3aIrG/12/cEBh4UC0cB2NJ1CwSwTLVzlYqtlpfH44faOk7Y/ONjemq9AsQ6cENJm@pQ/Aqfi@ranlfprxQfta@b6V6Vt5se@sSEo8OwYFCRJ2UxvQCzs9pjSop9wJp4drUqPqOwKnSzlfihrW7UZu07oualmZi9bBggwzLsfEq26wRVFdls1xbfUZL6EqAcd77dH7WboJJgsPaA632GReJ6CmeCaLujhQ@xywin@PThhR@EN5fftLujLVqy@w@JoHlMGiLU3m/edpzQU14HYbbslvN6KVeJ4W7/XyOswjCBRjUlJNx8Vz1Y1jl0vjMkFuz/GC0jR45jftyvwOttcO9CcEZ9Wy/L2ZluRYh6NHLP7A8K1vWHo7VWHhg23BzVgEg3QsKfP7zVqS6NkWU8apWX4EgZW@nzQml/D71PKgQsgYL5djGOWxe2K8qAFSyP@hwmEMB8XvLYTd2pWl5oVxfRRlaqR48gZTe3bR6Ge8hwPsTnzHDVcrGeB8P9smN3Hh@l/n5Xa6Hb/8W7viPfao2Cm2X1DqKRkWr@xhWWa32@zBt6ETuhWG3LW@0xBcb47KH4UKTMlo0a@XHuP9vldaKMXx7dHbY7tuTDPn4xhauQcgujz8IkEYBhMxndkuZ49TII3T8yJF2HY/@2aurQ61SdDIZbJv2HbNcv107iY7jPBNzdKdxXi5dad9CpwIspWU7P1ISLhGu/Eh6AkCSOdMDhFsQsFVRV4I3RywwDAMii2eYLr13xfJiYQbSQM1h2Qdpvk5rOaWbMWpEnEmki6Xd4rW0k9mY3Zrscb3rSds7vNnKxpck7uBDViygyUemBztoLad@AGLntwPFekk8D22ZI5ljNK63xdHkIB3IwZ2UEf0rC3gcuWvpww4qvLfAvjEnPcv/@tn@5RDSkQ6bsxKNgwwH3V0KejcHrIx01HPx6Pbdzjwj4g8vf44pj24pjEUzdxRnxrCiKVt6eX1XRfId3nhZdzzL/WsOBChaoB4GAnXGgcm35IuVqlAy9bZURB@DfxAzJ1@8ko1sGvBw5l@xbZWjpgEiFYkEQhqmWRvCJ9imkIW9v7PAHZemF4zZYUEZO//43vpkCliyqE5Wx4tr23NiKB6WixLQzHCSeAddbJFxqFKYiCTIYgdgIcuYVJQfl3lTgjm23zgCZq2SYHDsM3Ol4cXxDthMi4PY17HnV3oOSO3/z@XdvsNr8R36D/@LOBy6yMb@IP2r4Vi0WSgdQXqFfr1SZUr2plIuZmYkoWboSyfb@lUvHZRBQsM3FlmxY@20NlekenbNOC7UwFGKPj5mQQw/yAV5V1zSdNM6dMPNd3E6JdJKSCe/gUWAIlvutKcFccF@CxSW5GvpIR6ormEKtiwhtniId7Pn7zx2yFqLy@kme8pL0Jy3pvSnqp3GTk5K6ajRYrRbQf4q5g@2Nn2jXijCudzuwHszQDtoURgD83cOac/OnlPKe3zK9fY3DzoriQ62ylFad3bn7@6vzk4vL48u0FsHHBqZROw8i3VyYClWDsQfw1Cj22zQr8iFwaP202njG7ITxLARWF5GzSAK9HwEI9WxqWlK2iJuZ4kdcxS7Ksu1eZmo@BS1JTR86ZtFPByvG6mStmCoDMgzk5AbuaIQ@KM99irhg5ImkCQRoQxMCXCC/fthF2t5bBc4Yf4jswPSVjHYqRuoLaDoS0cuAUbw7DkdxKxOJ/CfMx@JGnMUeopzAHYOGp0dcGPj1@9fPbNyebY68Nm8JsgCw1ZO1ky8kM4mawgwOm4bh7mulNmO5@Z4YB7P6Ib8nY3sq0xcvdFdSkARpmD@Y2Tgq29hTj5CZoR3Ry7MVgSPt9sAy92wQNC1hUvqGy3FURJWCAvvRzRSIKCBs3N3dBwXBMIcJwPvHGOQbHeo63HSToUOOff/krPzzQSaD872l5AOX/5OWPBjJoc7eZ47hkDbLl3atzEoO34oT79myNJnQY6JDcAKJT1wcO3jCGIDhHdkXvqh@l/Q74CUIAZqLlQ2PHxqNRVxklybhmGOjfIU0c6Gw5ms5ADmArdUisjF8meJYD7LOxV9nbtQxAUrvJOmRbhENcIuUdqmoNVEi4ccfNTz2HNBoNIsaO7dHmXp0z0sjZH8vipyWiOYAVeCjQJtAGmqxaQF0rbabk7IKlYlOchbIlk24dvDyXCzgKhRUARMXPQcoPETxRmLIKdxvpLGFG9TYLcSC@CELiI5/YiZ6sIw064n2rorChu6ulUNwCWtNmfV0M4nsEu0CwmrhNdQhoyH9t0ZwAyv/By@2OqX3rbjuNstSd481DJ8r9IyNICzm6CEJcGj8FXIlSMkplw9pT1@aJmHYF2OKs@ApdwjyAeeVQ93M4jo9fnLz66ez8YuPQBIOU74PJRG41Ch1NL7a7y4J8T@czlv54aly8/vE0Y@Q6VmnVfay2dX4fsQcGe88XnTeHYhUbA1nm93bMdki1U5aEbSFkWWusAb7gK2QboyrqfNHuNlqdQNoY/uu2E02SnsdDTFDqxOw8k0y2GJhX2VL6ZXgN6vHIUQ0tQQj3y/qhjWwhHk9ElFpGn94YuIUv6KslejGnNO5gq/JjJZwH2fBgJ9IvOUiCW2Q1liNsLHeuI8Lzv3CJyZ2WS2YjzWc8s2OnsuwAgvrIdTh0zIwrz//YESLIAF4lq6QBEhFM8lludMvyAJjmy@XDvstWlu3oNqVgWXNBfVe7zPDBSb/aJwcjFEYJpB/xyHN7dbvZnpHlLvJjW@h6PPbcRMG965mO@RVQo6hIgNXwKG59Nw666T47ybbDC2xH/XwC/DoPx2SV076kWekNpDXkJeTvLmgAJT9NfIAbsMcbihaekj@FGjQGPsoZEm0YRUlp0P1@BUbXR3TWd4fgJRS1CAblB8ta7cXbagFyURlsKGfV73FddJ0xv@n8wBrH7Latu0GfzhR5Kqu1LnIHvsvT9zeyKm7oADvEkJ5o6N8/zZDNfTtJJ@HyJMD6xMkCFhg83UsEJ4JnTPH0CCQKLuj00R9pEIDKKIC2DwpC7AnQGanF7KhzcXksbc0u/CHdmrzvJU7kuReCL8wZdZaS1BfgED51SCfpDDoBeoX6rfE7QzfqcyXnNW8NcORqS8mNmlahnC8UckFeyQXoyp4/x0xmkQNPeaWLujgDIC3nqXXgJ3jWZi6o5@yGkus3S3nWAl4LBXUODb7Fhj7P2Qsj9xwcUxG@RFw7lFysojhMXbcWgB9KKGcUfXs8V0QizvB0Hw6fcwsFxEHPXSEC34zORYGZqc6FwXKnehogGUM/U@M7yvDrr5K1B7H64V5ZCQ9L5Z28RKQj0ch3Xn748OKmLrftQUn/pXt@fX7@b2pHkaUXZ6K1K9ZJ3hAkI29@3TeMT58@QehA2i29pXfVtiZ320prfz9fL@5V88WjoiUX6xLxLNOyVKVUUi86u0H9GVyKdS7LlbJ88RGPpxzuwA/7hWv5ivcd9iX9zEA2rx2VKL/MBKn1DHSmvLdz9AxQogV21WpHRJC@CdKtIH1qfBIkiISkVqu7WBQa7UZDb7VmLa3bagvSXJBmC0EqiciCvCA1Z403rIv2yxbvq/ALsPNneDa0bnt8/vPJ8cVJsdTQpNLp8Yti6eLtj5IFb5XVK1aW8fXNyfHLs7eXxRJv9ftX707ensN313XHcb8f98NRt3V0VNA1TTvSW13AZ/ZDoVVoJklCPlzl9Rm/ds/2zo4E6WVr9tbQGoDKz4L0hrXSOoBcR4W2XwWpLbWVw9JhyfTMG9O6tq5fh2er37MzVAtxvyqG4RGAuDPzcxiZI3Nk9S3Lmpn0rXlr3s5MPzyz@lCk8GP6UHTNwcwcmoEZWNadLh/@9c/C12chdBVCs2RmJtirOYDn8OzsNXQ2gIE/w49rmojqzLyBX9Oz2PXxylTNTkeAdLFb2RuX9n5pM8NTOei26cxNuiIpyp223K1LRtzpGFzTxRKoKVYvFldXL48vj6@uDMyfZo1c4aigHcHVbBUa6eNQ6reQhXpjpyPIyvT9@/f49356M@UlVng/Je/Ta7q8rT3fT@G6eaDx3QKucrYr3flChbTxWUeuyxxtRaHgNhXR6sxKA1ISmTc6AFtglSHiV/Yqaqu1V4H3vaqqKSbW7qofrUYjrSqpYSTKMzGMZDJf8B9lvmgo7FLxR1XxY3pvqQpUqxV4m82VWUNpKPgNPmGr@aKFRQY3h1JbUbvqYsG/wV1RG7zPlgpUYbz/f/QbxpCcEllaSGj/A7JbUSGboOrunlItHKQ/zR0gRhHLchloFGVbbreP8uX8/m77sJvv5pVGXs93Wt3Z@qXKEgHdylSkaUnIPUHS629EqyTKqDJ1XEMLPap7EN2XD@qykr9/Va2DQr5w1M4fHPDB8vmvOyq0hr5FuCTQKqKQRquRrScoq6UFtQV/c5LyF8qLOSgErwMHoqRrY53OzDQZfL3XzM0le1Fn3ZOFmEHznhXWvSLX2aKpOBdzdtS2uuJCzM17C/SyeUtl/rGyW6/nd3l5v1oHs27l0xoTatIiVNDYdthsAkuOiiQDh1UgqtmjQzcQpLFQxwVEvlopaiJXZlI9YI2kOBYgWuiBJKdk34Ro0PPsiISDwQ7/DmEP5IsU3D71PEy8MeqfhpHXn0IkuiNIMYXLP7fphNLpZDKly@uFG9fsz58hmoVLeI3p5oHFF9/dGB6Qv/8BRvUnzgj3Q9wEPReENKagI4al0kG1Uj0ol6rF6kF1t2LtVSpFq1S09qv7B2YRnFbV2qtWDqxidfegvLu7ewC1lYN9QaJB3x0YBngJSxQJK0DgjOezGniSLdRHLfA6fTpwA/qMzJS@@kzqZx/IpErEcrVjQqyOZxdBXiqZo1lTSAwRLiCumMUJzPHK4aQq7u2LtTw8xUOxDEUm5plCTBn0QZQ7oqi2D7qH4n5FrIEr1eTn1iER9w/Emri/L6p1kQ4rorhHSvtifQGYZhxY0kDA8uk6gT9NE7B@3ORYKERUOuKacqnpvxLJiizvl2RZlevQyc49ECQJKOIEiQclET5GNJlEATHrCz76v6wNH13X4sSOMEdjvUMKs3cg4mcAafCp0qr08rWipRWPBK5ce5YgLYQ@HjXZPaij8waD1mgJORmHl8uCpJXD3VDK5XLg8i9bYlk80xtG6sdbBnPiHfTr6Dv1LCxoCRHF9eE@/t8Ut8nVCqI/JLHQhO9CHSe0KKUW5BadaId32fgmsWME5Hy@XDdMz1XXXiNP7NoFO0PX7hL1259cb14tay0WCENAviDAmsX44uDj/sfqx9dvz96enR7VqrUqzHIp/qqGFetb8FNdqo3l8q5cBlfflDiC1r4qtUr7emzfSt10J0rZ3VcJvLE5XLKkATqnpW/a9F1rpS3v0xufRUCASPV3/eHQLf3u9aevkArLMiFWbu@b1uC/Dbi9OOMSUsS9iqjC7I8/Xn28kgSpQsRSBXSlYEAAaRj/VoLpd3CwV92ThF8N47FUGmqXmcCAQpA88belAseR@9rGtctgmQ5A4fUEcsbl9CQ4PzHJGrXufmNz9s4n9n938E1AvJhSY8GOhk6RLaiSPJ6YbHdh7maL8QrW4nqwulw@Xmo@X@bHLtz6sgij4FwjTQRgGgPeXXGbVp24DewMnpAwpCPglbUoNLGIiSrDwu2qdWF9XZxh0oLWa7istS8UOPiCo8Xpcfw@J5vXLV8BPR/3Dx0lba3eA2ibXYCRO6ackvk9ZEBGqCx7KJLfTMa99pAbqRlNDIVVZfp9JYqFkE@Kfl1AsvPjuvBHxVHnmLPVv/nPnzsfx22/W1f9ZoLPQsEHs3WtuBwknzT9pmbVx4BsPWkXCm636at/VMYMeb@JNg7Gxp5jdb6UdNBMxRWrxS/tQPsWdIun7aBgdYuTYv5D80vRbprFGfwB24pe8RdgXsZKJWl@KQR1uwF/mD7e4QRY64Jdv7tdAU2uFa/5pW13m6Za96BhoXAKxACecdsrFLoqDO5B5WbDuvf8uV3wWrO6p2kqQn0sH562Eyh0C018ryl2Y3b4pT2B9jUFnk0YxlMBeWh3VwbQH@BXBx5z8a1Q5zjOEL0ZoOc3m/kPh/kP@ebOzpf2TPO7Rc7@mrkSPCI/Q@TXdUTJf1hXLMYSFjMp4g9u7Qc9HxOxCNoHTC6O11pyDPMfoGa8mg2L/wY)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)

### Explanation

I spent a lot of time looking at wrong direction. Standard trick to distinguish C89 in polyglots is to abuse comments (C89 does not have `//`).
But we already have complex thing going on with comments and preprocessor between C/C++, Assembly and Fortran. I didn't want to mess with that
and started to look how else C89 can be separated from C99. All of this is of course irrelevant because C89 doesn't even see main C/C++ block,
it sees Fortran code (I guess because Fortran doesn't support `//` either).

So we have to polyglot Fortran and C89 with these restrictions:

- no preprocessor, because we use preprocessed Fortran, so macros would expand in Fortran too
- no `/**/` comments, because as I said I didn't want to mess with existing C/C++/Assembly/Fortran code

As it turns out, it is possible, because:

- Fortran escapes quotes differently than C. You have to double a qoute to escape it in Fortran.
- Fortran, like C, has typeless variable declarations (implicit type)
- Fortran has line comments (starting with `!`)

Main obstacle turned out to be Fortran's strict type system.

So we can try something like `x="\";print'(''72'')';end!";main(){puts("92");}`

However, this doesn't work in Fortran because implicit type is real and there is no implicit conversion from string to real.
`x="\"==""` doesn't work either because there is no conversion from logical to real. String subscription `x="\"(1:2)` doesn't work
because in Fortran result of string subscription is another string. `x=ichar("\")` fails in C with "initializer is not a constant".

Luckily, gfortran supports `sizeof` as [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZEOF.html), so we can use that:
`x=sizeof("\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts("92");}`

Added `(` after first `"` to fix flaks. Not after `!` because it breaks pyth.
`x` -> `p` for alphuck. Prelude as usual.

C89 doesn't default to returning 0 if `main` returns nothing. 
As with other languages which don't return zero exit code it is easier to fix it in polyglot than in the test driver. Hence `return 0;`.

Answer (score 9):

## 102. [Symbolic Brainf*ck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Symbolic_Brainfuck), 3004 bytes

````
    #16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]4O6O@|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"-' 101+-eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

I used [standalone pretty printer](https://tio.run/##tRZdb9vI8dlE/8G9jHZ15ZISPyV@iRSlXOLrB@LKiOP6EIq2ZYuSmciiIlIWXVl5LFD0HtpDH4or2qAFCvShv@p@Qf5BOiRlJ@m1fShws1@zM8vZmdnh7F6M0qv37y9HGfiwSGa301mSyQXCLaLlDKTrVTaxQVrsA58qw0j57nd/UqYuIJ4h/psdPkH86wo/VQBB4cH7VN7791QzAUjPbLGkp7dqIgXaJ4o4fPLixeMblw9GE11@HR6@Ojz8Shgynj4eEK1NXBAVjiqiemcpyvn5OTkHCHzZl0MhkPgwYL5liW7TtMVmv6nxTZfCTFM1TWC6LhwN23M3juNFOh5jS67gMhnH82mnsGoPgWmHPG@0@KNTvodQw1JWhIdp0ddKyo5cLvk@1ARgr3OO@nschZZZ6@@hqlGjhE6nDxx9w9Fbjp575xz1PI/6frjdNqRAbshy2JAaXuB5su/nvhT6AUc3HM23HNVJ4SSRo93ce1YKC574ldTGa3T1Uxw9KQwWh0/3Hx3tN3VPovqXjx439aPjL6iGM@PDtGC2iumz/UdPBsfPm3r11U9@9sv940Okp6Hf7zdkSZL6sh@iFvnnDb/RzbIMXpyJMkef@PmxInm46VOOPitXSkNUYyjg@vbAHPTvOBrQgPX0nq7O1BtVe6W9OkgGDxUOBgNkxLn6MlmqV@qVNtY0LVejY/VWvc3V62SgjRGNsKjXiMbqJFen6lyda9rHgv5HvR4kB4MERSX4WZarWSFVneA4HQwOUNgEN36JJVbVQsFcvcGqzrQSTs9UENThkAswYEPDXOjm62CxylIwnDCI8jgLCTT5YeA4Dh@6VEmHQ8VdLON5RnQM2WLFdnt29uTR80dnZxi@lOZevdFvSH2Ert/wdkOPjv3ChbJXG3I8W5@cnBTtZH2zrrASOVnDyQ5wphDLJknS3y09@TCerBFu/ouQTxH4BBgLjHCzFQRhb8i7fGUJY9HNaMaINsz1CehEGM3H4CRL0FqeB8w0BN83DZybtiAxteC2hVPN83YsXUiWhM9JsuRhs60K22w9VoJQFEEoiLveFxiyBQNn@YblHvNYQUNS8dVm6xdouW6DWMCEUNhuKxr2TPAqmb6ABsI8@aFqkkK6AJ5uKSvcBG1DYBe3kdA2md1wdqVbQ2MYafEttJHwIz4I@mJLtNpBLxRDkXmiLA79MP8YBJ4Chtx91HQ1WniPo7L7jGg64Ysoci@TeZrMInmWTKHluDwTKwDxAWzNaYiNfiA6TrWbKN7VBPwchRMEipEGDDzfezj@D5Eg@Ng2sHMw4tsNRkTFG3XrpcnZBPXMVbVc71506xs62rqleNiS@9W7wCrFM969HKURkA2pj5aBFpItqW8utoD@EzUhurxKwGi7rtiucMt2Me1r4o6jImeHIiNKR5flH4aZvogkHl0soFHdi2gazzm6@CS0G4ZhKDr2@efmvp5zbhplUFoBRCJVpIPtlAIppKnDrbLFBR70GiwVxslsNlpCMpnUKvrVKIWLKJpDGs1meJFAsspgnSxn43U8jmocxYzggINshOvDUbSKovVqtY4e4HGcdkYvX44WFbx7@8dfY/sHtm@q8Zt/OkbRv3v7@79/95e/cjj@9t3bP/zt3duvv8X251379t8bxxWm1cCw7hGNO0iWETgaGgDZVVyQEVtGDvdTtO96dXkFcQpxVtyw8QRUTi68oeuObdhOS7ebtmO3Dc00jKamNzXLthy1iZerrZm24WhNu@202u220wRNNxyLo9F8HE8UBS8rjRAokXh@OVuNIy/NxnEiX/kcHUeTeB7tQc7Gwh4d3xNgZQNp2UMVCHc9wshgIMCmyLoM0vhXEWrO1OYKk43RW9nEtEhHxJH0SAvR8rBzBiqPcUn4ISFC4IQ9Yhmkg1e7xP9Y6wGxHNIhlkUEl0g8oCUNKZoahJigW4S8wAON8Gt3i5rfu@TBJsA0LcuATZK4gr/oVmox4jAoj90ZkuqnqCKMZzxv6Twv8C4KqZGP41JwCxvRxMrCexUJ6oQqOphu3WWUrZZz5kiYUUByBHdbqfSjj3Ravuqk2WiZwV21ZQeI6ZCCjEs85hRb@caF2GlqUrPPVeFuahzdcuMY81jbAddxi7cGpmDP5@p8oRbf4qjUStoJrdfr@FZ57pMWGciesnt2@Er55hgWz5DiASDfv2d8ULhlNAXcvEt2fxezjcKWKaS08X@CjDt0USbnFvmL0F3GvC1uwmGlkPeGXs5GaQqHm3sXT1bzyyxO5p2DwtOjzlGG6kyDEIQ3v4hnG7sl@YelguhZQN9uF0fOqXVqnx4cD44HX/Y7dsfGpEbTOyExtDfzn7u0s@Bbbb6Fr50urYzTLIH6uiWno1sa0uoQWNsSAGdlytI1Oinu5Ydr@fvX9kfYf5ivb67L5x4qYn82nk5j/bOD87u6ovA8gFY330heVT3sHg@qI2bENIhA0SHp6dnpGcXEBEQ3MAQbCj6oFeUrHX9zxzFtk3L/Ag) because the one in the test driver doesn't work properly.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002881 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3057 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zXtbc9vKduazUfMPzksL5DYAkgAISpR4l7Rt@cT7bB8plr2dMknbEAiSsECAGwBFyjJdeUpVLg@Z1FQqldTMmUxVqs5DnuZ5niav@RX7F5x/sOdb3eBFEiV5T5KqQCbQQK/ude3Va3W3z@x4@PPPGbrYSehfDvwwYYkbJ6wXeRduZLBvL9mB7cXl0rYkcago7E0cLxiwZOgyLxhPEtb3fDeWHDthLTZOezGowDIscu2eAJP6YcSoCRud@8xjznjMznx7aDjM9wD7rFhh7ij86KFVHI4IMnGjceTiHrPAdXssHruO1/ccjpG5s8QNYi8MYoN5zjmber7Peq6PBisynAI6Y5N47ZNAaki9UGK4nPENopdvWRcwgbtg3B3bEWc8ZGMuhQX/08gej0GklGGnIDzxRm7MvESJmWvHHkkTTWI36HGZjZdyDpkdrHPJLjyb2aB3EvG@YzdKwJ7B@2VDN3LRpU3IB5E9Yuo08hKIgER6yE5cO2KvItfVgAWqcGPHHoOOayiBLCQMCTFicJU1GsrR8TMFqhMtDHucSJlo@9UffyfZzGiy7Ps6fk1ZrktHv33KrrIdKoMKdAb1jiPV1ljzC4vNTsfFb2admYNoLqFXCVLxmRmOE9PWxyBQT0CgaVORSvpFyRj7a4hZ44Yu1gxKQPWgDfY8YD8UOGfOJIpc0LESqn0Opv0wGECeYDaaBCSPgO0WoQInDHpxgbkXkFoYCB2FUy7hV0MPSotJJfYZBGQ7JHsxGLhAMRxge6lEF3jj0J9wOLSMEzJASAVNqcfnffYD69ueT01QT10JqiM3nvgJtZkEPdL8yAvcnsEWZDhhj4BG4QXQ2eiUf8D4Ga2NOk4UgKGIkLNKVT/99T/0BgP0c@g4YdRLzfUH1gudyQgE25xYG6ZIBhsGts/JAlyBsIvmQHBh@17PTgh9cJmi4ERwrNNw4vdYCITR1MPQGtoXGI79vuskrjDycJKAxgIb2efCV3jCcsH4yD6DYjkCjpuzrbODJ9CS4wqT0UeTpF9h@viIKbH5Tt2vqftbHRe0aYaWy5rmoA57M3L8E96U@wznh8OVPsl6XnkhjSN/PJzAa6AmiMfwJxEJ07HBTkxuJYH/K7AzLmjui2DqfJBOXSVy2RlG9oIxbiPCBqi9TiM37WGl0wXcdRNze2sWBuuEkSXxLTfhh1Mg5rSRE4VNB4TcHthAlaQMHQqGBEb@5Tpr5wEsnXo7c1lFP/OgHbIDOJtUGWs8Any7JGDQm9De2qAY2ZfoxRFOeqVJ5vWh5BHsNrpkjkuDAaPCFZ6OkEy4YcQe7Cjss6JeKpcfUH4SmYf6W3iPT@a9Oibmb6j5kPXdKfPtYDCxBzDkMEAT23HccZKOIHASJxgjNx0h/6inXt2Ih1L24CZu7t1Sf7@Gg7yP0F7qo20yewhqBFHrPkY5s6MBH4ms50UYL/7lTewAuLiBXP5AINcI@CDfQcJiaoKRuTPXmSQYbjDk6dBzhrBdoi4QA1Z4x5vo8WkdO1yO3l@iJmKs1uOSZJjLT0TGnV3opNHb/cDrU1etax@48tc/3N@zHY82dBwuSYSHWvtqmLYB20uFhvn8lGIJuL/F5M1H1jLAWMoTAv6OJqbI/XEChcGevUFAIHawnPjXPKMXBwqmCi/2IHWawsnWXz0/pvngjSuiGMhdzGXrzjxETIPm6RRNFQslSK4zDJkeMCWlQZX5jPoRZJlx5PCCvhZGyJoBOakkL1616OijiNFuTqisdRuOo1QKrC3L3QLmMD@GCQUT38fLJOBDTHW1K9ia48axgQED2RoUj4A6Oe9q8@uAyTAKp8yda3VlE7pfqJAnkzNv9p9QIw7RJe7gak0N/NPX6OEW4EIRspyK7hYEl92TcER@nr3hHBO930aYG/qYD6TxZTKEp9MdJtvNcOyCpGueRAGdCNJVrc5DOkUxPoZeoF4pW1tbSk1pKQWU9lFqUGmfSnmU9nlJ5yWCM6jEWxR4iWrbvAV96yrz9qLnmdYl1c4obv3kjVW7Xattdwt220qfJXpqmEwwdwBapwf6UbRmk4qaJremYNQ460uC/VdQzvcI@dj3Hs3EfQSIq9RBWiLrSLIQxvZ1XyqvakoiWr0wRxCfMb7cHEXI613xBgjgzkOy0VXpfdGwyte6QN5zu2Xfi4f8dg30Flm3a3jreHTW57cNALU0DEBMQVkSyYW7MopEwhCWP@VgozAIBSmQlxfY5kv@MDB7bKLnupO@RsyZizE/cM0zL6DyA2B6tcIh@2dn3l2gkAuRvnhuAIsmZ5vEhvBseGseZ9cEn0yixHd76fNf/7QHBdxWz9C@jBHQny8L7yE3UpXev1NbaVN64bfNmv048ZHuPdCHY1MQb/vLwua@auylC/OHZgOe5YFSH7xRhANXd9u@MTT8Sc9dPDd3ymV4PRwQrQNvxDWHJ8U23PPc0fxGMCPaU9IT@aHdM0Ui6rkrVQqhuzN7EAaX5tqsZkRnX0HjIt5gq8wzGU6SibhTsvmQ0rwx/e4bjClksWyfWa4ZxvaZd4cEiYjdu4xWjAVy03rft89F8T0VN7MqmIm8ATLbxfMuMER7CMjHtuOaU/64038Ek3jMlclL9/QX@eJ@F4gXOJhZg1XhLkCw6fPbLzE5bggOxgGRSos9@pqIvBtC9e2zS5rKhr/cfgjhIJ9nOnxH08nni9tMD1e52GpZaTy@u73jpO2r1c2txQoU78AJkTa7D81HmFS8ke3rpd5a8U7/upj6V6VN7se@sBEU@HYMA0lSMbsXUAu/3We0NE84E9@OVqV7THZFziLlvitrW7UZe07oe6llLl42IAgozLsZEq26oXVFfls1pbfUZT5F1EMT75d7/WboJJQs3WE6X@GRRJ5CmeCaLRjhXeJywin97hyww/DCFffNU9CnjVR9hcfRfW4MiLVvN@85D1korQPx22ZPeL6RqsTxN36vsRdhGCFRjVnJKN6rno1mHHt@GLNTfr9PFkjR41jcNxvwutg8O9CdoRhWy/LmZhuJ4jMaO@T3O5Rr@4PQ360MTBu3Oy1gEvXJsafPr3VqS6dkWQ86pWX4EgZW@rzTm5/j30PGQQsgcN8exTHL4mZDudODpRH/3QwizKcFr83MPStWlpYVxe69JlVjh5EznNqX90I9NHPcJebFzFGjxXoeCP/b0Ozcj6b3dV7qVrd793d7Tb3nvgs3ze@3lMpKResXtrCKxa/3WX1/4k7cjT7k@OyjC8P56qD4XqKKKRs19uncv7fPryKbZnF6u9fn2L6Hcf5gDFNjJwiiT8IHEoBBMBlf0@V69jAJXj4wJp6EYe@XW@rS61QeDoVq7NRNHqDiaBQiOQ1HCAmCr9BsGqrzbUVxv6ZZ/mXV80fvCeKJ6N5@lws9CEYRXEBZ3nmsI3rZKNfUkZTuJ3WZqlSryKkCN7mk@12jdpOHPAtD/5dMBHCUPY9CLgSStA/7Faq5HJ0hCnNWC0v38cRXZV7yrbflWnhcSPcM8c2L0h2ieLkNm3keOJHLV8YXa30sQ@v1kxECzCSMDMbhVNXO5zVNEo0oYBkEAFtA8Y0w2osQe2wxQ@SYcFivz9ptlr2a1Yo1a86aTK7JrNsVvfJV8aPZmO9gvRRN21m728wquq5klU5QY0WFg7o@5o@NoPY1uL7HH4LOFesssEd8@4PKC07rYo8FYR1trA3toIeU@nXg8WVMJ4zEToHYjnpF6xX/8vteut84cMHkyIvhLAYB7ZGHI3cYTvcF3hT74Xhs034l9YEszhcLnfqTQxZPvcQZim1GRJ2vn72qpHtE6c49Xk7IQNeoEEpFVR802IlQmqCmF7rCKlLEy1YLphDKT0YBm3q9ZBgbiNECx@V7UIt9EVASEViQRCFZVYE9Zz2XUkq@TvtxAt36YXjOl4eJkn/5vdgZQ6VHJkTlBXq@VbuGkcG1Wnw7ynHCCahedPLJjcIURCUhIyGZ0ACHTbviu8acoc237GCJ@mLDitCITasnh6dMP2IKHTWg/au611ezhy9//UO72G1@YSPT/dc/NWnJnMtN/kbfs2K5wBYg9TnZ1Xp1EdWrWoXJ2ZmcskWb2nwPd2lUYjQxlcpcXYsNqBHfD@d25075BhTfZQxo8NNGcxBjfOBV412LQdPMqhPfG3kJ008TVqbzGHDMNkpiB53RCQfaTKEm2Rn7zIZkK7rDrHIRb0IgPu3fjZrfLlb7ttdXZc2n7tmEr2BclIzSdpOzk33fbLR4KXJ7Ie3wtt91pl0zXkil05l9UyzNILYwAvhjk0bO0W@fXmWNVvHz5xghmyzPlTpfNafhnb06eX5ydPrq8NXrU4hxLrjMPAujkb1yEWQEYx@x9DD0@ZY55BF5bvyw23jE/Yb0KAVUVZa1WQMRDIOHerR0LKlYZV3OiqKo455kWXejMnUffY@lro6dcG2nilXidTdXWBgACQ9jcgK/uiAehnO1wV1xdmTWBEM6GOLgS4KXb5sYu17L4YXA9@kdQk/ZWIfirK6gNgMRrwI4pVvACCI3MjH/d6J8jHnkYcoJ6iHKASw9hH0N8bPD59@/fnl0G/ca2hTmFsjSQtZOKR3NMLXDD/a5hdNO@MJuwvQkw8IxwO8Pxfaa7a9cW7zcKSNL6pNj9jG2aVDwdcSYBjcjP2KwQz@GI@314BnOLhNyLPCoYnNsuUMmZyAAYznPFZgsEWzcvL2jDccxRWjifBCNsxyO9xxvOhTScc2f/vofxEGQToLyn6flPsp/JcrvTBLQ7ZMDgsalaEgsPzw/YTFmK8H4yJ6t8UQTBk1IXoBMwxtBghdcIAQuiF3xu@pHbf8AeUIJECZ5PnJ2HJ8bddVhkoxrpknzO1L@vsG3FtwZ9ABfaSBJNn@c0Lkc@Gdzt7y7Y5kgUr9YdMi3ewe03C061LQaTEi68MbND2cOazQaTI4RobrN3boQpJm1323LH5aEZgEriVCgzdAGTVYtUNdKm6lZO29p1JRGoWIprFvHLC/0golC5QWAaPQ5SOUhYyYKU1HRzrE7S7hTvVyEOIgvgpCNSE78dNaiIx0dib41Wbplu6tlbdrOW7NmY10N8hsCOyWwmrzJdBgs5H9usJwA5b8Q5XanqH/pbjpZtLSdw9sHiNSbx3@IF3ZwGoS0zfEMtDK1ZJa2TWtXWxsnctoVqKVR8RldYhxgXDmu9zEcx4dPjp5/d3xyeusADIdUboIpTGk18h3dKLS7y4Jyw@YXIv32mXn64ttnC0GuU7XKMQhilWjcJHMTtpuU3oH9jdhRuI2bV9xCZBW/tmOepejPeIZ9u/dVrbkG@EQsf97CqmpX83a30eoEmVvoP286rpYxcnRCDaVOzA@rKWyDx3m@2Cd5FZ7DXu45h6MnBOF9Wj@Rs9hloeMupZbZcy9MOp8hGav9FzmrNq5Rq4kzQ0IGC/RwHOmXrCUD7wqXI91ay14nRGSS4ZKSay2Xwiaej0Wqx4/c2QGi/Ah5JIeOubcVCSE/H4aU4HmyyiKQmVCiyZOlS54YYNwv14Z7Ht82sKPLlINlzak78vRXC3rIC6wOQcArhVGCfCQe@t5Z3W62Z2x5ROC@8xFGPPa9RKWDCTODEi5wo2rEgNXwXTrX0Kh200MUbHHWIc@PS5xMIK@TcMxWSe5Td1F6iTyHPZ2gc1iAy76bjADX54@XLrl8l/021NEYclQWRLSBRU15MEa9MrAbQ3fW8waYNlStAA/zjWWtDlrYWh7JqQKnKkT1a1r0XhfMLzocsiYxu20bXtBzZ6oyVbRal6SD78r0zYWiybdsgJ9QSY@r9G4eVVmMfTtJB@HymMfN8V2tLsf19WFTrRrDWKLTGwjVgfE0ib5HEROi2h/ZY6ZOAopeYmYw/qp21KAQJ5HG9BZNTlMWsHyeB/l48AqD8ZZ9XvJ8Oh@p0qlY1WxCz/Q1Dnr0@OSNWdsyjC7KHInGspSfP0HsQJmtJiEiRJMa7xazKf5qRNEU6QxRJJ5Zjlai5DoC1MZqPpAHQz4AIQvONWs9ZitHsBqBQqrVai3VxnXvVmUwi9sTi2Gi2w1eaxE@Qr7pLj2kRqe36VwW0jYPDuXgN24QYLyqsJkRRiezJzCySCss/itBYXngc43AP0o3/W/O2UfKlR8iMsmadZ4g1ueYnj90WCfp9DsBzdH1S/NXpmHWr9Ss37w0EVZpLTU7bFr57Vw@nw1yajagwOLxY8or51nELe8N2ZBnANKzvlaHMSPOaWaDetZuqNles5TjLfCaz2tXaPAlNo2rrD03s48RJhTwJRJDU83GGo2FomFYc9BHwyNrFmAwV6rM5BmdmyX0WS@fJxqM7Hsi4IvZOc3zOaJzavJMtp6Gq@ZgtPAh13Ty888ZaxeZ0/7uthrul7a3chmWOZDNXOfp27dPLupK2@6XjB@7J@cnJ3@idVQl8@RYtnbkOsuZUsbMFT/vmeaHDx8QyLF2y2gZXa2tK9222trby9ULu5Vc4aBgKYV6hvlW0bI0tVTSTjs7Qd3zvHHc6@EXDulgHUKZGqnmES7VOlGU8rZy@o4OhO1v4Y//w7V8pfsW/5J@5iC3ry2NqT/OpEzrEWxpe3fr4BFIdfP8qtUOmJT5ImUupcyHxgcpg3g102p15/O83jbyGHN5Pd9oNxpGqzVr6d1WW8pcSZnZXMqUZBJSTso0Z42XvLP205boNf8jBP49ng292x6ffH90eHpUKDX0TOnZ4ZNC6fT1txkLb@XVK1Vu0@vLo8Onx69fFUqi1a@f/3D0@gTf427r4CBv6Lp@YLS6oGL2Tb6VbyZJwt6@z2GUPG3NXpt6A0i/lzIvOaTeARkdDfA7x7vHB5@lTDvTVvdL@6WiX7woWufW@YvwePmPvTg@RoU3K34Mo@KwOLR6lmXNiu7r4mXxclYchcdWD0UXf8URil6xPysOikExsKz1ju75NzoOXxyH6CpEs2RWTKjXYh/PwfHxC3TWB@KP@POKRSJwVrzAv6Jv8evde@S7xU5HasNgu@XdcWn3xzZ3/@Vqt@3OvKQrs4LSaVerVaVbz5hxp2MKq5dLMFmCmM/fv396@Orw/XuTMttZI5s/yOsHuJqtfCN97Gd6LRKh0djqSIo6ffPmDf3eTC@mosQLb6bsTXrhzZT3KnIYHqSgb1bPN1NcF3d0cr3Arl2q2i53r@aapj3qKHVFcKKqLkIaVbY6s1KflWQeKVThKqxtmo12y1qrtVvG@25F09Ui1e5o76xGI60qaWEkKzM5jBR2NRd/6tW8ofJLoz9No4/pvaWpqNbKeJtdqbOG2lDpGz5Rq6t5i4oc7gqltqp1tflcfMNd1Rqiz5YGBik5@w/6F8YsHjMlM8/Q9BCwnbKG1M/VdnbVSr6a/jW3wIwqbyvb4FFWbKXdPsht5/Z22vvdXDenNnJGrtPqztYvTckwmNzCappWhqQnZYz6S9kqyQpZUZ0WPEPfNXykYtvVuqLmxMVyy6tiVfO5/EE7V60KbLnc5y0NzdG5jCsDS2Mqa7QaS/WvLEFr4XfFUgGjPL@CRYg6TDBqupLZ6cyKRQ5fP2tmrzL2vM67Z3N5AZ0aFu9eVep8iVu@krN21La68lzOXp3NaRbOWRqfP8s79XpuR5T3KnW4fSuX1hRRkxZR4ca2w0cYPD1ZkgIRa2CqeeYOvEDKjK@Zdr5cLpsl3Gff7B6VZlKdloLFurOsy8LSWaXKO8ywOK5KCPTOoOgp2ysikPd9O2Jhv78lviNiRe7vImhwfZ8WUSigQ1zj96ZIIrakDDwCwhlU4xqd2O7EdaeTydRdXk@8uGZ//Ih8hF9/@N3f/Rl@v8fvb8Tzb/65Wqb7H373X//pp//xjxKef/mH3/23//WH3/3V3@P339Pf39/8/fS3/1v8@7/pHxX/8ae//T90Ey@SRNxvsfLeomBJL2gNo2qJHR2PPqMUuVXpjyCC0cQZ0j6Zl9AkjNC4KBkksFKpWilXqtulSqFSreyUrd1yuWCVCtZeZa9aLGD@rVi7lXLVKlR2qts7OzvVArNK5eqelHGDntc3TcxnliwzXkAGRqc4G3TeNTSGLSnTc/uIPx@xmdrTHmV6iw9sUmHydqVTRM7HQ2SVaeyKHLPKYmRKoFwtFibwR@X9SUXe3ZNrOTzlfXkbRW4PM5UVFZiurHRkWWtXu/vyXlmuYfbXlcfWPpP3qoid9/ZkrS7rCgMned0dlGV5l5X2ZPmtRwcemFyfg/KFSJY8MXhyw2D46bpE9eOmIEuVqyrjllHtyGLcCCNUVEXZKymKptTRyZa8brpanXgEi4LDBYkyaAKJVXjkeuQmkyhQqzqcDtOrWn0uSPovazRF54jX7YhiZo4SCfNuVabPAGmoVULVKp/lagVLLxxIYkTsWlJmLvXo1NpOldWrdQpH4KUbLSmrEFnKtpTRt8OdMJPNZhHOvGrJ2/Kx0TDTyKRl8rCkQ5EKxQjGIuRpMVOKXNqj6NH/wxRTTaVMvAxYnMn/f14GMDTRp1QnFydnUqd6SZNlRxDU@JLhR5rYydVy3Tv9Px61FyRpu3bKz/O2u0z78lvPv6ps6y2eOiB/nDPIdj4@rb7be1d59@L18evjZwe1Sq0Cv5eJP2th2foSfFfP1MbK9o6yjYComRHMWXtaplXaM2L7MtNNd1LVnT2N4Y17tZKV6dPUvZy5b8/sa6UN79OLEY8IQUjlV73BwCv96sWHz1nTVBTGrOzuF70h/jVwe3IsVKzKu2VZox3o@N37d@8z8F1MLpVhgnkTMbdp/kkJw7xa3a3sZqSfTfO@pR/ULpOnvou8YjLalD0dRt4LmzLLYJlBofBi8smNll6AkRugRQHyA@vfUtew9on/J2B8k4guPlaoYEcDp8B3BFiOjm@3u/ARi90klWppQ0Nb7n@IMcSKdbFPRV149WURWGgII48tio@ULKle06ozr0Gd4YkcK8VA16JFvklFWljhVHhdrS6tb@xwSlpovUbLWvt8XoDPBVmCH2fUE2yLuuUryBvRBrijpq21GwDtYpcS9k5RSdn8GjaQaKvLHgrsF7Nxoz3SSW3BEydhVZl@X6liLuWSwqguEdu5cV36jepoV5Tm1r@MHj923o3bo25dGzUTeubzIzi@c9UTILmkOWrqVn0MYutJO5/3us2R9ht1zIkfNYsABm7qOdaulpoOmqm6Yq3wqR3oX4Ju4Vk7yFvdwqSQe9v8VLCbxcIMP4it4Bd@hPAWolST5qd8ULcb@FHGfU0SmATydv36fhuanKt@81Pb7jaLWt1Hw3z@GZgBnXHbz@e7GpD7qLzdsO4/fmzn/das7uu6RlDvtveftRMUuvkmvddUuzHb/9SeoH1NxbMJNL4G4tHuug7QH@irQ8ZCfSvSBY0zIm8G8kbNZu7tfu5trrm19ak900fdghB/rbhSPBE/I@LXbUTNvV03LC4SHkaq8jde7RsjFzO5AOuDkAvjtZaCwtxb1IxXo2H@/wA)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)

(All verified by me, @WheatWizard, or @stasoid (thanks for the help!))

### Explanation

Symbolic Brainfuck only uses symbols. It contains all the usual brainfuck commands, plus a handful of extras. The only new command I used was `²`, which doubles the current cell value. `▲` and `▼` increment/decrement the pointer, and `¡` is output.

Nothing broke. Cubix claims it's failing in the driver, but seems to work both when run alone on TIO and when executed on the [ethproductions interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)

Comment: It works on all non-tio interpreters

Answer (score 9):

## 104. [Paintf*ck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Paintfuck), <s>3159</s> 3123 bytes

````
    #16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d1114O6O@x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"-' 101+-eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ ppppppp*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e*///X222999686#
````

The code above is generated by [this pretty printer](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOoSA/pzI9J79ED8TgKkgtylHQzS0tSbNQ0C1wVVAv1o9J1X80YbZ@urUCkF0CZHdC2WlAdg@EHaevAAT66go2qOb9/w8A).

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002776 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3213 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tXtfc9vIlt@zUfkG96UFcgyAJACCEiX@lzS2fK/njkeKZY@3TNIySIIkLBDgAKBIWabrPm3VJvuw2UptJbuVTDZVqboPecpTUrlVW5V93U8xn2C@weR3usE/kijJcysBBaDRfbr7/OvT53S3OnY0/OWXFF3sJPAuB14Qs9iJYtYL3QsnNNjXl@zAdqNiYVuSOFQY9CZd1x@weOgw1x9PYtZ3PSeSunbMGmyctGJQgqVY6Ng9ASb1g5BRFTY695jLuuMx63j20OgyzwXss3yJOaPgg4taUTAiyNgJx6GDZ8R8x@mxaOx03b7b5T0yZxY7fuQGfmQwt3vOpq7nsZ7jocIKjW4OjbFJtJYlOjWkXiAxXN3xDaSXX2kHML6zINwZ2yEnPGBjzoUF/dPQHo@BpJRip0A8dkdOxNxYiZhjRy5xE1Uix@9xno2XfA6Y7a9TyS5cm9nAdxLytiMnjEGewdtlQyd00KRNnQ9Ce8TUaejGYAGx9JCdOHbIXoWOo6EXiMKJuvYYeFzrEp0F1ENMhBhcZLWacnT8TIHoRA3DHsdSKtx@9a@/kWxm1Fn6rIq7LstV6ei7p@wq3aI0sEBjEO84VG2N1T@zyGy1HNwzq2MOwrmEViVwxWNmMI5NWx8DQT0GgqZNSUrpFwVj7K11zGo3ZLGmUAKqB2mw5z77Pscp607C0AEeK6ba5yDaC/wB@Aliw4lP/PDZbh4i6AZ@L8ox5wJcC3who2DKOfxq6EJoEYnE7oBBdpd4LwYDZyiGA3Qv4eii3yjwJhwONaOYFBBcQVVq8Xmffc/6tutRFZRTUwLr0IkmXkx1Jn6PJD9yfadnsAUa3aBHQKPgAt3ZaJRnYPyM1kYdRwrAEETASaWin/7mH3qDAdo57HaDsJeo6/esF3QnIyBsc2RtqCIpbODbHkcLcDnqXVRHBxe25/bsmLr3L5MuOBK812kw8XosQIfh1MXQGtoXGI79vtONHaHkwSQGjjk2ss@FrXCF5oLwkd2BYHkHvG9Ots4OnkBKXUeojD6axP0S08dHTInMd@p@Rd3fajnATTO0TNo0B1Xom5HhWfhS7lOc7w9X8iTteeUGNI688XACq4ESPxrDnoTEzK4NciIyKzHsX451OKO5LYKq80E6dZTQYR2M7AVhXEeEDlB9nUZu0sJKpgu46yrm9NY0DNoJJYujW2bCC6bomONGRhQ67VPn9sBGV3FC0KEgSPTIc66Tdu5D06m1jsNKeseFdEgPYGwSYazRCPDtgoBBa0J6a4NiZF@ila4w0itJMrcPIY@gt@El6zo0GDAqHGHpqJMJV4zIhR4FfZbXC8XiA8KPQ/NQfwvr8dG8V8ZE/A0xH7K@M2We7Q8m9gCKHPioYne7zjhORhAoiWKMkZuGkGfqiVU3oqGUPrjZN7duib1f64Osj5BeYqNtUnswagRW6x5GObPDAR@JrOeGGC/e5c3eAXBxo3P5PYFcQ@C9fAcKi6kJSubMnO4kxnCDIk@HbncI3SXsfDFghXW82T2y1nuHydH7y64JGavxuCAZ5jKL0LizCZ0kersdWH1qqnEtgwt/PeP@lu1otKHhYIkiLNRarmHaBnQvYRrm81PyJWD@FpM3H1lLB2PJTzAYQx3DFMoyjONxVIG5cePhpGNArOar8PJ5fOyTZM04vHTjQKQ7XtAxR3aEwWQuejC7k447u0ERz1sy/EMkXWAa70esDvv/wwQqoir9SNGqPP8JAa8VyXxq5U2IpwxADmSAU2o/Msj9egYLcHrpd1XZ4HpvYITIOSbTKJM1JKjWki9PghGZDPaGTy/kL3wdwsz0YVqk8WU8BB/0LpPtejB2fFW5ppSKxjtUtSr3DhTF@BC4vnqlbG1tKRWloeSQ2keqRql9SmWR2ucpnacIzqAUr5HjKSpt8hqU11bmzUXLM61NYpuRC/TRHat2s1LZbufsppW8C/TWYJdghgCt0wvtKFq9TklNkxtTEGp0@oL6l4KzPa4NLx1/IDmzcRDG7Lvjp0dnJ4evfleXzUkUmp7bMX1MiGcjDDe4v7Ko/wpj/1s4H@xbl@aEPlyVlRMrLXFtSbLg5fb1US2vSgrCb7qAFsFCjS83z2fyelO8AlyJ84DUd5U6yxtW8VoT8MBv1@y70ZA/roHeQut2Ca8djTp9/tgAUEkmJMxu5K8TX74hb4/mxCCAbz/lYKPADwQq4Jfr2@ZL/jJgxzbhc91cXEOm4/Qn8ADNjutT@gEwvVzikP1Ox70LFHwh1BfvDWDhpLOJbbAew1szCrvG@HgSxp7TS97/8oceBHBbPEP7MoJreb5MnIFvJCq9f6e0kqr0wR@bJfth4iHweKCNrk3upO0tE5vbojHBdH1oh5Dm5UKa0EZ6wL49pO8YKt6k5yzemzvhPL0@UYnavjviksSbZl1uyO6ofmOaFfXJHQ@9wO7xVkSY5Dor8QpBODN7AOLMtdDNCDtfgOdiNmSruAgzSTwRTwqFHhKkO6b7vgGaQOaLdsdyzCCyO@4dXCQkdu9SZDE@yPLrfc8@F8kzSm4mVRATugPEXYv3XWDwReAuju2uY075606b4k@isRAFpe5pL/TE8y4Q1@/C6/RXibsAQabHH79G7bgidDE2CFVaitDXWOTeYKpndy5pdhz@ev2hDgfZLNNhT@rdbDa/zfRgFSmsFj3G47vrd7tJ/XJ5c22xPsIb6AYI6pyHxiwmGndke3qht5a80@YuvIlVapNJsi9s@BmeHUFB4oTNzgXEwh/3KS3NHd2JZ4er1D0qu0JnERDeFVOs6ozdbuC5iWYuPu6yhTcdvFUztOrFH6uq9JXMmE/hSNFk/JlmSZ@v3cDqe55wRV89P@ZwQTcmV/4O1fkCiyS8aIpT1nTBCO5iVzeY0n3ngB0GF454bp6WPm7E6gssju5xZYBrfrt6r/uQhtIqBX9stoTnG7GKu97G/Ap7EQQhwqiIFYz8veLZqMaR6wURO@XP@3iBADKKxHOzAq@zzbV9vTsUw2qZ3lxtI1J8RmOH/HmHcG1vEHi7pYFp43GnBkzCPhn25P2lRm1plCzrQaO0dGkC30red1rzc/w9pBwUnsN8u@TbLJObFeVOC5YEEXcTCNeflmM2E/csX1pqVhg596qUEEXYHU7ty8X7z5g67uLzYuoYX3LXGK4cVSiXkIhD4S7/Ob3t3N9b78us1a1m9x4iYk3M554Dc82ft4TLCnnrV9aw8vkvt119b@JMnI225LjzwYEC3SfyL0cqn5BRYR/PvXvb/CK0aTanr3ttj@25GO8P@jIVdgJn@oRi4/vwGviT8TVZrjXwcuK/vJ9Rw/FiSAe9ayhRya81RaWH/aNFYEuLnL3AEahNg5A2o2BZ19dxE/ijUYCYNhjBa/C/QOiJN8/3xcTzmtB5zqrlD@4TuBzhw/aDnBL4q/A/IEf3PNLh4Nxp9q/bmsJdoTgHLpcRe/lOfEnPuzi@yYp2gsD7NRKCMe255JbB2aSdxIcldXo56sBT667Ws76A/4uwENyiEDjePC1At9Fk/FCbYoWJb0gtV4ijXLKThjw3TPZNouXmZOq53w0dvl68WJJkKVrFnozg2MZBaDAOp6p2NqtpkqhEjtLAB9gCim8P0Qq92HmKGDzWmMO6fdZssvTVrJKvWHNWZ3JFZu22aJWvFR/Nxnxf56Wo2kzb7Xpa0XUlrbT8CssrHNTxMG9tBLWvwfVd/hJ4rkhnvj3imwKUXlBaFTsPcCdpu2lo@z2E868hC@5XB6FYPxebNK9o7eSf/9hLduEGDogcuRGM08CnneNg5AyD6b7oN@n9cDy2aReP2kD06Imle/3JIYswfLtDsfkGb/f1s1elZOck2c/Gxwkp/RoWQqikBsDBjoXQBDZL05B0vKy1IAohxGTkw2j04mFkwDf0uw7fmVnsFgCTkMD8OAxIq3LsOes5FMr2CLEPE8jWC4Jzvm5JmPzzH8V@EQpdUiFKL7rnG5hrPTKYcotv0nS7wQRYLxr56IRBAqISkxEITchqQKcdka@x7tDmG1nQRH2xjUPdiK2cJ4enTD9iCm3A03pz1e2r6cOXv/2@mW/XP7OR6fzLH0ztKuGb/JW@Z0Vyji1AqnPSq/XiPIpXpQqT0zM5IYu2evnO5lKpxGhiKqW5uBbbMiO@S8z1zpnybRm@9@aTQaHtVz/C@MCnxpsWg6aeVieeO3Jjpp/GrEinFGD1baTEvjKjfX/aYqAq6Rn7xIakK3qXWcU8vgRDPNrVGtW/Xqw8bq@vEJtPnc6Er5xcFIzCdp2Tkz6r1xo8FTq9gPY9m@9a07YZLbjSas2@yhdmYFsQAvyxSSPn6LunV2mjkf/0KYJ/KMtzpep0hwEf3umrk@cnR6evDl@9PgUb54LK1LMgHNkrE0FKMPbgww8Dj28kgx@h60QPm41H3G5IjxJAVWVpm9XgMTFYqEdLw5KwVdbltEiKMm5JlmU3ChPz0XdZYurYCZd2IlglWjdzuYUCEPMwJiewqwvkoThXG8wVJ0dmdRCkgyAOvkR4@bWJsOulHF4wfJ@@wfSEjHUoTuoKajMQ0SqAE7wFjEByIxHz/0eYjzGPPIw5QT2EOYClh3pf6/jZ4fNvX788ut33WrcJzC2QpYasnd05msFdgB3scw2n/eGF3gTJ/v7CMHC3LUq2BpemLWIXbuR2PIdrUp8Ms4exTYOCr19GNLgZ2RGDHXoRDGmvB8vQuYzJsMCiGhIhzR9M95mcAgOM5TyXY7JEsFH99j4vDMcU7k73vaic5nC85WjTUYmWY/70N/8gjke0YqT/Kkn3kf5rkX5nEoNu76cLHJesIbZ8//yERZitBOEje7ZGE00YNCG5PiIbdwQOXnCGELhAdkXvqh21@T34CSGAmWT5yNjx/pywrdIGa8U0aX4fBF7f4NsczgxygK3k@60/TOi0CuyzuVvc3bFMIKlfLBrUXdGgPhYNaloFKiRduOP6@06X1Wo1Jkdwe536blUw0kzb77bl90tE04CVhCvQZKiDKqsaKGsk1dS0nbU0qkqjULEU1q5ilhdywUSh8gRANMr2E37ImImChFUQuu/MYm5ULxcuDvwLP2Aj4hM/s7RoSEdDom1Nlm7p7mo5nbYW17TZWBeD/IbATgmsIm9SHQYN@S8bNMdH@t@IdLOV1z@3N523WerO4e1jNerNQzFECzs49QPaXnkGXJlaMAvbprWrrY0TOWkK2NKo@IQmMQ4wrrqO@yEYR4dPjp5/c3xyeutYCIdUboIpTGnUsi3dyDXby4RyQ@cXLP36mXn64utnC0auY7WKWwhiFbzcRHNTbzcxvaP3N2In43bfvOBWR1b@SxvmkY/@jEf0t1tflZprgE/EsuutXlXtat5s1xotP3Wr@0@bDnGljAyd20KqFfEjXArbYHGeL/ZnXgXn0Jd7TqfoMUG4H9fPqSx2d@gQSKFh9pwL0594nmSs9n3ktFq7hq0mTtIIHiy6h@FIctKWjH5XfXWlW2vo64iI6DRYYnKt5pLZRPOxCPX4QTTbh5cfIjbl0BG3tiIg5KemEBI8X1tgQGRCgSYPli55YIBxv1yT7rl8u8IOLxMKliWnzsjVXy3wISuwOs8Bq0THHIagzXM7VbvenLHlcYX7jnoY0dhzY5XOWMwMCrhAjaoRAVbNc@iIRq3cTs6DsMWxjSw/@XEyAb9OgjFbBblPnUXqJeIc9nSCxqEBDvtmMgJcn79eOmTyHfZdoKMy@KgskGiiFzWhwRj1iujdGDqznjvAtKFqOViYryxrdWbE1rIIThUYVcGq39Ji@zpjftU5lzWO2U3bcP2eM1OVqaJV2sQd5CvTNxeKJt/SAX7YJjl507t56mYx9u04GYSrEys3xne5vBzX14dNuWwMI4lOksBVR4@ncfgtkpgQ1f7IHjN1wo8tRcxg/FNtqX4uikON6Q2anKbMZ9ksd/Lx4gUG4zX7POV6dGpQpbOiqlmHnCk38nv0@uiOWdMyjDbSvBONpSk@fwLfgSJbTYJHiCoV3ixmU/wqhNEU4QxhJN5p3q1EwXUIqI3FfCAPhnwAghecatZ4zFaGYDUCBVfL5UoijevWrcygFrcnFsNEsxus1sJ9BH@T0wHgGp1pBtQThG0uDMrB7x3fx3hVoTMjjE5mT6BkoZZbHLDPLY9BriH4u@Swwc05@0i58gJ4JmmzygPE6hzT8/sWa8WtfsunObp6af7GNMzqlZr26pcm3CqtoaaHdSu7nclm035GTfvkWDx@THHlPA2/5cyQDXkGID3taVUoM/ycetqvpu2amu7VCxleA5/ZrHaFCp8j07hK23Mz/RhuQg45oRiaajrSaCzkDcOaAz8aHmkzB4W5UmUmz@g0KXWfdrNZwsFInxECn83WaZbPEa1Tk0ey1cRdNQejhQ25JpNffklZu4ic9ne31WC/sL2VSbHUgWxmWk/fvn1yUVWadr9g/NA@OT85@QutpSqpJ8eytSNXWcaUUmYm/2nPNN@/fw9HjjUbRsNoa01daTfVxt5epprbLWVyBzlLyVVTzLPylqWphYJ22trxq67rjqNeD3cwpKPRcGUqJJpHuFTrRFGK28rpOzrbtr@FH//Dtfyk5xbPSbI5yO1rS2PqDzMp1XgEXdre3Tp4BFSdLL8qlQMmpT5LqUsp9b72XkrBX001Gu35PKs3jSzGXFbP1pq1mtFozBp6u9GUUldSajaXUgWZmJSRUvVZ7SVvrPm0IVrN/gCGf4t3TW83xyffHh2eHuUKNT1VeHb4JFc4ff11ysJXcfVJhdv0@fLo8Onx61e5gqj12@ffH70@QX7UbhwcZA1d1w@MRhtYzL7KNrL1OI7Z27MMRsnTxuy1qdfQ6bdS6iWH1FtAo6UB/pOUaqaa6n5hv5D38hd569w6fxEcL//Yi@NjFLiz/IcgzA/zQ6tnWdbO8e7xwSzvvM5f5i9n@VFwbPWQdPDLj5B08/1ZfpD3875lrbd2z9/oOHhxHKCpANXiWT6mVvN9vAfHxy/QWB@9f8DPzecJy1n@An95z@LXuzPEu/lWS2pCYdvF3XFh94cmN//FcrvpzNy4LbOc0mqWy2WlXU2ZUatlCq2XC1BZgpjPz86eHr46PDszKbKd1dLZg6x@gKveyNaS136q1yAWGrWtlqSo0zdv3tD9ZnoxFSmeeDNlb5ILX6a8V5KD4CABfbN6v5niurijkesJdu1S1WaxfTXXNO1RS6kqghJVdeDSqLLVmhX6rCBzT6EMU2Ft02y0W9Qajd0ivndLmq7mqXRHe2fVaklRQQtCWZnJQaiwq7n4qVfzmsovjX6aRpnJs6GpKNaK@JpdqbOaWlMpD1lU62reoCSHu0KqqWptbT4XeXiqWk202dBAIAVn/5/@gohFY6ak5imaHny2U9QQ@jnazq5aypaTX30LxKjytrINGmXFVprNg8x2Zm@nud/OtDNqLWNkWo32bP3SlBSDyi20pm6liHtSyqi@lK2CrJAWVWnBM/Acw0Motl2uKmpGXCyzvEpWOZvJHjQz5bLoLZP5tKWhOhqXcaWgaUxltUZtKf6VJmgN3FcsYTDS8ytohCjDBKMmK5mt1iyf5/DVTj19lbLnVd48m8sL6ESxePOqUuVL3PKVnLbDptWW53L6qjOnWThjaXz@LO5Uq5kdkd4rVWH2rUxSkkdJkkSBE9ldPsJg6UmTFLBYA1H1jjNwfSk1vqba2WKxaBbwnH21e1SYSVVaChbrzrIuC01npTJvMMWiqCzB0etA0FO2l4cj73l2yIJ@f0vkw2NF7O/AaXA8jxZRyKGDX@P1pggitqQULALcGRTjGp3YzsRxppPJ1FleT9yoYn/4gHiEXz//@B/@Evcfcf@teP/tfy8X6fnzj//uv/30n/8Rmf8b9//C/T9//vE//kHc/PtPuP9pLe9Pyb0GJ24Jbf3bn3/89//15x//@u9x/6fk/vub909/9z/E3/9JfpT8x5/@7k/0EB@SRBzcYsW9RcKSXtA6SNkSu0IuZSMVOmXpd2DjaNId0l6bG9NEDvc6LxnE9EKhXCqWytuFUq5ULu0Urd1iMWcVctZeaa@cz2EOL1m7pWLZypV2yts7OzvlHLMKxfKelHL8nts3TcyJliwznkAUR6dQa3R@NzCGDSnVc/rwYR@xmdrTHqV6iww2KTF5u9TKI27kbrbKNHZFxl1lEaItYK7mcxPYtOL@pCTv7smVDN7yvryNJNepmcryCtRfVlqyrDXL7X15ryhX4EHoymNrn8l7Zfjfe3uyVpV1hYGSrO4MirK8ywp7svzWpaMZTK7OgfmCJUuaGGYDw2C4dV2i8nFdoKXKZZVx7Sq3ZDH2hCIrqqLsFRRFU6poZEteV3@tSjSCREHhAkUZOAHFMqx6NXTiSeirZR2Gi@llrToXKP2rNZzCc/j8dkh@N@8SQfduWaZsgNTUMnXVKHYylZyl5w4kMap2LSk1l3p04m6nzKrlKrk0sPS1hpRWCC1lW0rp28FOkEqn03CJXjXkbfnYqJmJd9MwuWvTIm@H/Axj4TY1mCmFDu1z9Og/HMV0VSoSLQMWpbJ/5mWghzralKpkJuVUYpgvacJtCYRqn1P8OBY7uVqunU98HsZXXhCn7copP4vcbDPt83eud1Xa1hs8/EAMOmfg7Xx8Wn6396707sXr49fHzw4qpUoJtjMVfdKCovXZ/6aaqoyV7R1lG05VPSWIs/a0VKOwZ0T2Zaqd7MaqO3sawxe3jAUr1afpfzn73/YO1lIbvqcXI@5VApHSb3qDgVv4zYv3n9KmqSiMWendz3pN/NXweHIsRKzKu0VZo13s6N3Zu7MU7B@TC0WoYNZkiYXL@PznZCL@c5xVRoTPxReVOxkEP39RgGUol3dLuynpF9O8b8UJpcuYre8gnJmMNgVth6H7wqaA1l8Gbki8mHx0wqXhYGQ5aC2CTMd6XmJN1rL4f@QiTyK8@PCihB0Oujm@EcEydGK92YZZWWxiqVRK@yjacttFDDuWr4rtMWrCrS6T6IVGPcLnvMikGE1161aVuTVqDG@EdkkPdC1qZOuUpPUcjoXb1qrS@n4Sx6SB2mu4rNXPZgX4XKAl6OmOeoJsUbb8BHoj2nfvqklt7QZAM9@mdYJWXknI/BIyEN@ryxZy7FeTcaM@olhtQRNHYVWY5K9EMZcycW5UlYjszLgq/V7talcUXVc/jx4/7r4bN0ftqjaqx/TOZkewleeqK0AycX1U163qGMhW42Y267brI@336pgjP6rnAYy@qeVIu1pK2q8n4oq03Memr3/227lnTT9rtXOTXOZt/WPOrudzM9xgW87L/QDmLVipxvWPWb9q13BToH@NE5g3snb1@jYfqpyrXv1j027X81rVQ8Vs9hmIAZ5R08tm2xo691B4u2LVe/zYznqNWdXTdY2g3m3vP2vGSLSzdfquqHZttv@xOUH9iop3Hd14GpBHvesyQHvArwoeC/GtUBc4zgi9GdAb1euZt/uZt5n61tbH5kwftXOC/ZX8SvCE/IyQX9cRNfN2XbE4S7j3qspfuZWvjEzE5By0D0zOjddqCgwzb1EyXo2G@f8F)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)

### Explanation

To output in Paintfuck, you traverse a 2D grid and toggle pixels in that grid on (black) and off (white). It only has a few commands: `nsew` move along compass directions, `*` toggles a cell on/off, and `[]` form loops like traditional brainfuck. The 2D grid wraps in every direction.

All the Paintfuck code is on the last line. By selecting a grid size of 9x9, we minimize some of the necessary movements. Then, it's just drawing a simple 104 (starting with the rightmost line of the 4, then wrapping east and drawing the rest). In the end, that gives us this grid (red pixel is the pointer position):

[image: paintfuck results]

### Grass

Thanks to Grass, I had to avoid ever moving west.

### Underload

Underload did not like all the `*` (trying to run operations on an empty stack), so all the `:` were added to appease it.

### Wise

The Underload fix left Wise with too many items on the stack, so I `&`'d them away.

When I came back to this today, I discovered I didn't need to fix Underload after all. Maybe something in my golfing of Paintfuck or something else I did dodged the issue? I don't know, but it let me golf all this out.

## alphuck

All the `s`s needed corresponding `p`s.

### Incident

`<space>e` became tokenized, so I put all of alphuck's `p`s in front of the string of `e`.

### Cubix/Cubically

Cubix, as usual, needed to be moved. I placed it before a spacer `x` in the Incident line to make sure the `@` didn't create a Cubically command.

Comment: Still a handful of languages to check, but real work is calling. I'll get to them myself in a couple hours if no one happens by who can check them for me.

Comment: >_> I already said Archway(2) and Set are on TIO pls add to verifier

Comment: @ASCII-only the TIO set interpreter is too strict. It errors on lines not starting with set. I see zkl is also now available on TIO as well

Comment: Oops lol fixed just need to wait for Dennis to pull

Answer (score 9):

## 156. [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen), 7154 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rb@vKlhj4@TDzD@YLt@x7JFkPknrLtry3nrZkWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQoUiap5z4@6MwMOunuYCa56TRuupO@tzsZTAOTD0FmBkiQAANMvgb5EScfG4O5/@DOWkXqZcve@3RPgKEtsli1atWqVatWrXqywxv93/3uAC@6oimLnqKZtCkaJt3V5amo@@nUgv7Ey0Y4EKQohErqvclIVE3jmDqgOZqWVUHuwjttakNRlZeiDv4Bmh7rWk/nR7TZ501aNAR@LBq0NjHHE5PWpP3RgjSdHWkD2YcxR7LaAzBT1Me6aJLwEE03VIUfdbr8i5DwiwTHOoQbdEZUfhj9YNKCNhrxatcAyAhNZ8qpbDH5AkOUpq803RARjyAahoaeMZqeZ0XhBWgcQHld1orJ0vmLII6lz4F0fqyIc5rvGKbOC6asqRjE0bVSo1Z5GSNAN@u53EvfIH3p01Q6NxGGO0GkDCq61p0IyB@zL0Iw8lSSFdGgBMj7GT22S9KPDvqA1kW@a4FRkqbTGIUeDRVapoXxmO4ofN8v0IoMsDk2RotYBPQSwpW@Qc/HI9qQR4DF0EbiNi0GrYpilzbGoiBLskAooMW5KaoG5Njw0zLQPpMVhe6KCkTYkCV4ARk9Mba8LCL8VFejaLiE8YtMrN8ORYBRxRUjxDGUBDJCw4IDrqz4MdP58RiIBGbWgHBTHoH8yabToEXekFHCIYohql3Cw/Fa9jWaV7dzSU9lnuaB3olOcBuijgXqJ3jpvqiLgJJfS59rpssmsABZnKQrIq/TdV0U3bv1YCdJSEzDFEzMiJ8U4empM1vOOaEorRh@fmxSB3qwfl2geNqfoA8fT@CXcDhOqGwpQ38@vEe3JfZQ3GPdxbvpxI@0wdzfi/Cbcx2mpz9TgJUCrig0o41NhveNgUCfCQQyPDrR5ZsG/GNlK2H69EVZbAmYBdWF0qDzKt30kpwJE13Hqr1hKj@ETCua2gN@Qmb1iYr8UOkIC0UgaFAzvbQ4Ba6ByJMy0maEw/W@DIVmYJFsVSZLQRGGgooC2bM5ukrX0JQJgYOYhokCCFyBqIgxL9FNWuJlBaNAOKKyqNZFY6KYGGeidrHkQQGJXT@9IkPQugg00qaQHA9IiQfUp9FWLSREATAUhEayikE//cM/6/Z6gCcpCJretcW1SXc1gahSnhAL@olGgdVUXiFkAZwXU7eiQwJTXpG7vInJqws7CUIESXWmTZQurUGC@kyGqtXnp1AdJUkUTNESckv7eukRP7R0h2xJLmR8xHegYEkCJG2SbR/9KQ2lJIjUAZEZ32hiSjHaN87SToP5zvXx2PXxw70IxLn97qNDhumdgMD5j4gXvDnfk5xmckc7GiZvaHKXGi/MvqYGaJ9AO4SENhZVl3MHh9Pr1DtOtx91mst9IicEvySrXZfzFGTxDBJ2uk@EhHAnHz@cvIi@nSSgmSEarK6iS3A7KFA5pFJMmREvq/7xgm76bNdWmGY8Issx2L/ljYx56Te1PA5I64NyqaGAgB7yG4oojl2sn3OjmkC4vfnGgH05fYHDzvCx/OBxHjg921knGCCnOxnFylqXNVRbyriPDQwwRTXGoL51lF2BB@kxUIubYAJ46Q6Ra6L6QbMQnTgTnbpId0CRruSIVEmrymF8HypKG8OmCq3gdmu02N2q0KAMoE6bxiutrGgzSJjQhm0YqBAVE@d7UEQQ2cpQ0sqQlSLx2c3aUAXFgtg6Ih3zdWSoDFjtQLfbsr@VRwAPBiwYwGZVli0dNOIXgEWw2sRNxaFlCerUCNSEvqAFEXUPKCHRalgwkQmphwYYP2gGsb5AOLxb115VNVNnkr5bUNZL5t0ahZnfrlSocGhJnNEKr/YmfA/tLxWi8IIgjk1bYUFODBNU0st2h3j67EbUb/Spw08v0yaNid28bqWByt4qPbtJ5FHL2BaYTwGlSvO2DUl3ZR3Uk7J4mToATF8k7vgeQXYI@N7xBgkrSwCETJyLwsQE7QaCPOvLQh9kF6lTLf1oNUYvkwev7dRBw/ukddJIDHf2bYDyM2svJONNFD4s0dd4oJFFVGc7HqTwtz3ex8wboz2ItTWJ0CBs@foZ3g@y9wWcI03V9iAFRq7RIshuiFUOYJHV0BqEBmxlfpHKujYR10UEZQbaA2o@yF/fNMfGMbQXstmfdPwgKUxdX@TNsorCwpj6QjY1y91RtA6oZwPqJ7NKgREmHXn@IkPEb12GA4OagiEmGXQCWvCnCUidyykZoDiJfxqBt4IcRIETFNbdAYAEyA@MckkGUck5UCq1hSq4HH5SlfxQ6Rxe2oEV1@EGB8Za8yWtjVAL0S1iIKDFl9JBc0mgrWzdT1Q/v7fJW7cBxL5zOv0DTVZdn50fPnxwHjvPQMN/@PARXKfo@oguD7g@EpePuBDOjy4Sw0tcGHpHYqDfg/P5boV57n7AYptj67SUxy7@7vg4@ODl7zj7GcCnG1QdaDaA9uED8DjdiQQ63W7H2Qwy6u9Iu7lPo3auCbo8tplQ4Ke89W5zIUjYII/Gmo6G7Ak2tu/zZJTQoTUE41Xou3Tn/R17/3D/@b7ruX92ejG2@4RPdCBTkJ5r5O/p2gSaTfdd6NjHPbjdd0FoLDsJJ@s8crliPgUS4t3uX8TcHt7itsspgtZ23d87gak2f@6Evk7wzb0Bt3vNKqADG2iwDV1O/@cYpN9xP7g9Tojrdnqhq5FwOoEzAjLBIJlGySQMyoEApmvFna7eaAjqkRYMBW0Kn26ZFfDKHFmeXfJYm07HdJ60rCq0l0ACNJfddRdH1VSfOiGGMLFSte2ESGcMIYgfNh6oGOUdGEQsyXOw9KHiLlYWDTbAaNSkobunKaK/RWwMBw2ST2N99e81aypWu@AXjE0hggEDzrHCC1Azd9HdO@h7QAiCyjD7Q9wnrxC/tHlI9@RLeYSWQeBV5F9XJub3RDb6yF4wkbBPoEvAVbS9oXEXCdfytACNdg84Lc5l0zLGQRBqGOWCN1xuNP@SlvmEVhs2@UjUqutO2mNNgI6LCE0/hlq9QDqrTmVdU5HJ/iygBok9wTJ4gXwfe0GMksl8IPM2f/chB4698ua2eLuN9SVzBUOgGVVTtJ5GHwEAiqbfbws2VI56fyJSotDXaMc9NCGBM5rpilMGBdIBuroPtpAP7A1RJ63tOpo9eEOZ2gSa7a6oyCPZzJNRDEXFtmmjd1ehaSiADYKKLJqUbVBumisc0NioErVnwWfnqHEMSiRPulTOZB8ryfpFwsFMDJ1R5A7ksCs@jsCyUETDQdMHdFWE2HaE5VCpapqZIJUUx05eXwcItIIvZh6L@VQ1WW1byZB4hjyaKDwmZsHXyLtFYH574EXStdHaijJs3h4GkZvizgAadi3s0BCGTuzhsy3/KPqPcOjLL1A9QaB9mvW69rQBYwiIw2F@YTymeh4PQpLhsbWnDRknKHGIzK93Vp6fOfYZ/dfjY1u26jbGfeFvR1oj5whyQ50Y463MfeYCxH9qShIq27V3kHgPfYAGrCzC4T3DgjZ4BGG7WkdU5pGQT1Qkvzlf@tGAiYQo60H7um9B7IlLzZf7IlAmWCO@ufQigNcpi8I6qIyiBuqhKBtkFHVbKKh1O3RPOVaN6U6b6diEBDadW9o33d8rd2wjIvIJEjXU0IbbuB6hBxpGLGsUo6HyOqYEmpTcdkBfEfU6xKoXo45EbnsAju2OHlRyHHZErhRw0Ar7mhq0a@KMgBGTlSADbskqz1TJA43XffTsmuE7xHREaQIqnwGbAt1fAPPFYwRS6nTkt0CBL0j66rkHTJ909rEN5Kv/qqdG7zDenOimInbt53/6vS4UwOvi6fML0sytHY/ANyIb0pulZUfFF3LbX7IEZjBRZJ6wgbi@hFLgcZCMV9aO/ahRH9M@X5/XoXAXq8IF4cQbVPZ35MyiXBeVSVdcPfcnQli82x@0YqvyiOQInmgOEfP2jegverNWfGJQKBrfJVisZl8WN6VtlYs453uQOWZLKYFK/Qo6V51OejPaC70rc2LdcYD3S@Uqj/G3nyvHu0LGhvkOJzKawXfkN/iIZETekmyrwmB/yCcp/NByPqJzf2at7Ohyrwf9QPv5Fhh0@k3RGIPhw8zI4x2xWLUeNGnl@fdw6op1fwtkNb@1drwFCFlVyO3nCB8RBwFqCMoOTrP4ttgkv2CswncW2JPp/3wpwgRJswxKJiF4PGwQW@j1sNxmQmc8fjs@mhQkfjy@P7Y190MQCJokieKXai60PvKIV3yB7pbzTUW86mdvXHtAB9ARBTNa4Q0QEtNmsziFYiG39wQXGxQBxWXjekdsN@SsRl/fGsDbxBnLgqbIxpgU9@rlLY34cuhjgwZn@MhtExXfXvO3C50GbKx9a9f@Sq0JJg6ivSFHX6GkrPErHCHcEgy/9hbvBG2GvzfNhL42Fa37/oZruZeqr1BBPoVIhizsid4VviSuOB1Dbvu5ONxLlSkoe/2P6StN0/uiatABP7vq8OMYOHT6rQG1er78tkwbsqIZ0LPA@3u8gB6EYVj3/dK8zTaZV31kWGPbvT/aXqJII0cnyf2NwuWVnqZEYj2Gh9ubEjDRJdT09vNrNdxaQ3HcFzXU2ujRVM5@vqnah/D/JeEgQyk6jpluOd@xpfapM3us7e0MQtcAJ0L2Zy7HxkhMP2N1@94qAF3oz/jF6vk3aD3e4u6q9RgviMkMNh1GiMfAYeqWGf03SS30fmrdr9NRr9BGv5SJrcIdKiJobHJ/VaR0gOV@ZgyOZb9eY0nKRJyIezVIuTMQcV3JO7rj64li7Wwc2kMgDDAPB0DWUEu7Q/hVVGN7jm/vKhxekaGSf9Ga2atqxmBnj7EPXQFHBR2vI/bUyXincLd4V52o1fc51x@varbW3SESQ36uRop92WbaMcUNkfzeMtuzIw26vdoIbAj1K8rfRkrGlKz7DmLis8E8kHH8TX8X7zG9nlwB@xXsEShVeWj4cBDv6xRP4K3@OgGOx6FHpormAu9vcXufIu1omvJzSgf0aVdGMw2MT1xF9aVSemX72PNs9GZkwsBRjo701piE1dbYnUfgHnaU3yzoCmTJJI3D15Tyq0HDd1qtrSHEL/UhocUmAz@GLqzcb9FbxcrN@WP@6LsErwbGmJXjPWRxf/Br7KPxyuglQ8g47GwNNG8mBg5e6J/xAjgld32G0BdHInl9x@Lnu4OJsXq8CTTX8Lcn2M@QMdY34o1lqPAq3ncGtbdMIlNTRYMxeb0nYl9FEXmwRi3ft5Tsauh2L3PzI74n5r4oWZthB1yBQWa7tpz7ByCOrUlRAaJ9QY1Y3UBNHYoLY/XcbywvBCjPyehdbPsquYCjm1@s1X5m73D1F2w@ta/11b7Y10nNWL@9VTdAIk1rRel7mQD6@7wxxCUnRCFt@nh9Y5u7iqYoX8NdVIiWetS0/QOvWVzr2YWoPwvvgu9AgP344hgdtNuESaQBf6vu9MUJNE@GZmpj0Ufe3gJVcITHuu8fS86XnQbdkkW9a0234dAeb8odRaRnMpAwMLYnCPaPHnUUjcdVTe9Y8MCZ1fNrxqMETf9Sk9DjNXM8Jo/HsTIxyI0M4fqk/WOTx3SOEPo1siCb1kSnJbFiT@sIfflLhdcReVOVh4xd@@3X/VK@q4tJxmXal0FvvyIDq/SFH2UgsR1ew0d@f72Xi/Y68XeNkfRE1xdf1g27U5Tr4VRrEgAdbw3G2PNOe4JJs4@z@atZ63dmIuxpqjcFihjSaDT7RBYsE@7NoaGdlQc2C5Rg0PwClwRNGH7RlnhzsNKe1URWCfLW3Cv4vxzReAe/NQNWJSuH12vLDK@95Bn8ZN1e4GqsV5Ef5FVBF8lKs9XKI/oA179NkCJT0/00gXO5eI/H7aasSDjQ01MBbAVF1vHi2j5ribBBK7JhElhZou/u6MPP82P2mHumE7Tj2EE/PFhYySqz7HxMFuBWrah3h/xD4tDp8zkPnffqMc06CaioQL97Lyi/AyfJ5GHRuck6rfLW2gJ0r3J6Yq1ZNPpkXTDU3i5ogQYYjkQSNN1aeWct76zj7NB//KuuvVwaLAWDHskG9LN6Ki7x10ZiX5t9tNK1U0@Oxzwut0Ycsz6qGEzdl07SxgzVhbVKWpvRjVw9Zq@5tDciwEsF5XqLCqtQ0WbFBRemVWgWNV1NtMTCTngda5UpQVMmIxX0c9fsG366JpO1FBN9M0MOLgRTTR0bqa6XztNdEcflyRIZYpcpmjYki9WQkv/4V9ZKU7JQBkQI3avkyUrzrRRxPQxHlncKgjYBqldIlqKu2SAuZDLYBhPs8oBQi5a/G5ePkCWwIIm@1QJQTMZaBJpO1mhflnbiTglcVnYiS67DZPW8ecc@JH6kR4z4n36PcX@2@eb4hS8aMRxeegVy8oxytR0chuBNqJN2HM4ddrZwTT5Zgr4WKnuzjgvdpLhWCzpHZDk/kTtxRhZ0kkUWKpo@uE5eNaB@wKuboLYqTeLQNbHsa1/NpMO4nQRMVh5c1gYAsjwGFydilMM5/QPdR1nxCTQXZuHNYoiC62FHidRqbjW4PQPOZMTOhEwFTQP@QDBBsnP4mDg9Iy5d7Gq4Pv3uu/t5gPXdz6PZB8ZYMef@fv4LNnAD3NOg6T/8lsEKlC1lPh/6z9gffjD4Be1wPDtPrBUBUMsPP1fylWytnqw3asDNZyuzBzlNH/EbTYGyQFbd9DWFLPwHtuiyaHxZe6w1yPoNwF0u@pCnT3GbkdtNbS8uIaA2qx0@x6HlXIOADbwd@wvR98U3xK3w1wC2ZpJk2taidIUIki0zTmNbg3pXsoXlgtUdLJU1R3B5xh5VSHjkoBPAJR9w6St5RL/OpVWCH4kHFOOXGfU@jn0ogFcbiNcAyKR1WphfK9zK3N7MP/9/kOMxtGt/2xwTHO/mGCHeyzEAbqKRGLlkvtioZncjgThtdnlBP0PHDX8SqVvWfhFLujR7a8JKMxET3bCXIK91q0FPZYOY8ChvErYM0Asm1ZHMCBuoXawFi3RSMUCTd7ugmjoLEzUbqHQ/WQhkrQbyqbTjAJjlXze0XtpBIayReL1EHTTXTAAt9r0V@ZDAEcwGtWdPzb3I/PQP/8zaR3NvgvsPbPecTcHbH9lvErj/wSqE4@DtH63fAvD2S@vtOwZZ@XrTgJWbNRORgc18hTZILwNZNOLnW7nHtg3bTlkFO1ceAa@nhHUIbmVrw5kNHtddEzgPxQVsRyWNepmkJ@oPLlzyfcwwaIrguJCfrDkR51Yfg6wAf5rgDihoSphIOBLiwMgWfdMVQrKKs4eLHCyEbvcxSCU1lceJ7zsCfXp6SjsMgVfEROTEYjlzyH8XdHy/JvQQYCnLarmjIQ5E2cSAsDM7muuQ93BujIqV08k56YcTMEisEoQ2zUUcAOJGb3W1zBEaTc1mFYiHKs5NovgXK2sMTCGVrLITrX1wK0Q@QGThxn06L6V8s5QBV3ltyb1/uxgcLQSrIdixY5@Q3X1H35v36oO9X4sGgfnNHpFTwf2HezZxraUn@Xr3kOvl3h/MDf2ppmq4vCUH1NKuABMIMlzEvVWnHDYqoBdr0A@AEuoM1EFBlAfa2Eims/lCuVJ7tfuFQDpfgjlp59mp597n9949rB3OF1K/Ymoqx9SuUrkVK7ep2owQI8RmmPglmftSe0npG6m3rDUkr9MmAa8S4tivRUyGZHw5MpPyGvsmlNkCTFtz3K9Sdbk/P989nJ7dqwevkv9h387AA/8RChe47g2yL9BJ79E5@dXKmDpuATf8q9WWAcdm3@t6Rar1vvF@e//KekP5ZhPLag0ORVYfrxcfU/43VudA3v2MlRTZwWERtqIXdM2KVA5J3SQoUK9G@bepoe28vN77bi@yXTOpbHVkyQY9XoU@jC4LFrRBFLTV3SW7yaDDkzc3fSTod2E/nXQFF6TbA6pi3b/uymR8ktdXC2TXITVxJPvqK3pQcWw2pdi7MfqQN0XunPCJuzm9Xmz63t4MvzFWZNOFG0XmfuxOQm5cbswAd4o7Lebu0/iDvamFXu098ZDtK5UJ8KuijelNFz4jrlxV6MXRmQkgBzEQ6cJkBHASeVRFbCVEuqT5IDLw0bki4g43bNh58I@6YUjd3xfnXbkHLY3L7QWV9AuO22x84XHnhuoEPWyx6hyXQmwz5mdt1tniGH/H@2W1K85duI7@@AG5A/7OWWvqdDteyQDZMWRvoOm@3Dq0Uha8adfazbabFwohHl8rgt26E4/7@waFi4GhBwIp1ky9CE5oQ13SiB/TrgnZe2XQfpq8uu5dqtcwdTftO8P2bEartMdD@i7wIAF@msSUiEtWcIjRhVuWXUwCyhl9DbWLj6U8pu84v/8B3CQRN32Iow9pMDew3@6mwDSFKMcELTTA8HeMFM2gl4YUWc9DkixFdk8A1N5gUpF7fVIBgRck1/TZt5utCFs10OJqPH5sl8auOozTIBanezQGoN2j5la2KfDXXs4JXEMlBlBp6JTKoFA@XYqqCvXVBTIzgtpJ8xMQMt3tXZ294d1sxSYpHFgkXtjrQ4HQ3S3aWednRQN75pA5IT3gk2do97@/x4Zfspv@BfPfMn7m5LPrUEksGDDG3Geuw36C8wSPPJ5D9ch1qKI58u232HF@PgRr59Hv8DvmAOQ7VNwnIM9gHSUO1ZND/tR12E0EjkgMePV43J8hwo8G4/98yD8zh9@CNeEFH92qna5Dg@yaYv1@7hnowxpyyHhBZj7j7iFycgYmfyh7PEiD//ARCfiRua95SLtyX2NIH/3ENnKZ3milRnZtlXVJvDoJxGKg7X281uhhstTfmgJ8XAFvb9DeE7bPPvrd7w64CHS3PkaCLs3zMcyeeJxh7sR5QB98cjBHDt3x@T7jm9Kiz3kn8WH/00NlWKncuO9ddJx2HqTLDi7k@I6OB44Y6oA5Yn@IMsz3338Pdih9d@Y/8z@473zOhzuX1ZOK0mfR6JE3EjvyfnI@brpuUdrtCgTcwK17OkzfR3n@yBMKfFJPICSOV5DmwIn3GPw4Ohyms3j95//9P//qP/8x@fsV@f17WZbHRrcLP61PD@klXEOJxn/iXna33Dy6O9LSBQY@2H0JlMlv4OIqTmc46Kx9h3sTP36AP/IP1/oV7x@Ij@1NQF5fH2jq4Ew4WB5wHHewIH@P6ObmW5dv/u7FcFzg/hs8dyby4dM3wFnRQ67j408bFjKOaMyhacSnDymEae2A7pa3@sdzH17UwWqbPy/Vefyj6x38q5r41xw2h77msCrgX2qIf1cd/Csui8ttomIJL3XwYyLhefei9/j5/Y8rF3Xw/en3ib/FhdmiDqBXdHB29vD87PHd@b/znJzY/6BPTtZveFkuIODB4/Oc3p2e@s/O5me@h7M76uAzdTB/pg4CDhD7@yPqIDE/rRIq7zJnq9zsXEXwOfU93FWKYNDXvYFT30Egl0x7A7VG6oCDt/DmFQOD@FrNJjPlBkBXitlkLXueb2YbFfA3Hh7PPn3y@KGEPgF/zh6AovkvPGeehGma9O3jkZ/@iutxj8t6pQ4yZ/MG4zsFoovUQZWk5PM/nj38QB3cHdy5PB89H1mFnbLckBteaeXNf7k8hwB5zg40ne2zfa4L4kuzYoNdsIs5O9LKXBecIvyxI3DKrDRne6zKqhwXKkfKn3awvf0/KmtXZQ3waRDXnLMmomYlePbK5SvAKEHqA/iTWZadA5lzdgr/rMKR67tHFjLqZu/vqTva8b0IWsjPOf2s0x9xOuWHcGT89Pk5EHm6I9ZKOP5wh3shHxy01/l4fwc6xvlwcsAY9/eMpaIdgZDjhOyXfH5@fMwk68nHRwbHeeanh55PHt8nuBJnnlP78fGge3by8f7Yh9JtSbj/8YA5/Xh/FvShO@IBhgfA75Tx/MxrgxKeH@4pp2vWarXw15pNZ5aLOCy/@9Y6FG8tBrwsF3rBhaDMvvi7jvlrAXO57sIPn5/dbve988Rp7zx20WTrsYO7nwckOuBAy9kVd0PDyQXRPIuEaffZWSQMHpGY2@di0bK2otw7xuPxvcNPxhL8ZAlcIpHUdX6B/QdXCJC44uFE4t7B64/3jrvAA8YN@@IRWtN98aDb4XZ/x52eQhqYRMAN3g7n3KHpTvrz8/af6/PzqYtcbvxzu9HTDQJDnmduFwC4w/A2/@yiT12nLvQDL4z3@fkMnQTuM7juXO4H9/Oz5Qd3l/vUwnrmBsbR0ED/V/oHff7/n/@rBm2ACfB8gNagSofCbldnIbpDEVfME7f/Eh@AsS5H0BkEjjucvPPu7tNR8Cgauvv4cOQ/wp/r9P7sYU@r5wYbBOryquoluAMsWOrAf1J1cAGHE6viiWBvtFa0Hh2Mn6CxcEIdQDQHXAdQU2gozLPTtfhuGkP3GZY9TUqTdj/Q7ufPINJWIFiLLnvC5f5@zqJeod30SSdx@PmAfz4h@OlnxwrcrhkEv8t5QmbkHJ8dh7x@xz04nh2HnzvPaFYfcW5ivYVDJydHIcsdjYGbO3Jbg8xgfp2s3RAiGrxwgiro5AAl1wlMdEOuEh2xJ6tgSm9XTU84HP7ABOAx/0UkG5gf2dfZ0Z4rFoh5jjyf7o6gh4FF8UB8f/hAneB0lzW35vA5rApOx@KEiAPaMOI0qNpT8bDima/@jjJHlovDX/aDQUGPsAO9/BkdZaHHr@AOJU2SPlj@0LWlO6IIvQtRUVY786EDpHRnclf8QB2gvQfGpSHCNarw4kQUZ5PJTFxfadk45gcDfkyun37z@z/95n/46S9@@dNf/P5Pf/Gr3/76V78Pv7@C3y@t5y//VTyM99/@@h/9zz/9@V@A57@H37@D37/97a//6e9ZP/L@H@D3f275/Qf7twVn/SjA9Ue//fUf/@Vvf/0P/hR@/9z@/enL309/8m@s///L/kPnX/z0J/8Bb/bL7/@S@ut//Rv8/@N//df/7jf4/7/8i7/@1//kr//oXxLHn1mO//uf/yvr/l/@7u//l//uH/@Xv/vrN@6//@7911/h/@v/Cj5fT@fX4PmafP1cn1//jej523BjkwoI1K/@8Kd/@vdBTv8E3X8P3PBPe3zW5bEB/gA9fzhkWbDA7n/YhvyB4cAsopktzz@gf7jHZe/cBhLw/7MfGBbMN9aCXOPchvzD3/76H/8l@P7wiQY/G/Lvr6Lb@mYHck0n9jCstP4AgP98C@YPfvrN7/30l//9T7/5s59@80cUR@OhnB/oD1SAxife0JM4iGt@RIWDoNZWbm7jDoaIOwz3fVYwzmZ@/LTjZeE@2gdMAD@S8A97jWpM42hF277EPqzi78Xwkf4EwdAEkVboFO/4Aj4p6L7YvZjEWYxOUF46loBufQoBE/BOwtFJ3qHBwoM@E1RmBUHTGeAHtmbzOfSDvqe/X/mfWaD0GUX/SKBtNAkL0Y8UeNrxfyRoExhnPqcINvy3jT90428VsLqRV8r2mFvA81ceFGTIS6JTUbpRgVs1f35R33rWs8n0BRWhU@VS5sUjbAOF6WI2V1@/Rq3QVdTwGkU7Wyy@fLUfbe34OPEjF4pS8IS3CR6ggi0MHr01J6dj@k9PQdTv2IfPoWggFA6FA8FIJBwNcKFIPBQJx4Isx0bYcCDAxUOheCwefabjFHX22Xd6Sp3VsnVAUy/TXID1U2c39NxPVyrXvmfqDAcsE1YzCqg@@wyDorCN/UCHo16v3@@HGz695CJP/@F3KxDu7W7fgYNjubDDEWEDUYcDGlLfR8dCpPv0iA7SJ2PIXXFJXeHUXZyz1lzJiBRcuhjHVSbQNM9Ussing6e9TcZve8IDvdCpy72@SZszbQ1gGAb0Kda9jVVPY93jaNEdnsffz70gBXH7Mt/3MK00iN@rEOU1OHUBFsoIz2zBFbQmDmDJEs1SfiyrQCAeC8fiwUDMG4vHQmEuEg57uYCXi8aicdYLrI9xkVgYWOuNheLBEMiEF0o/HI9SB6LalSWGOaIOOIeDPGVVwK37p3gGgubvn1EHXVHCBUn03NV10wfdtcckRjuCsXuWhogOLkLh4oCjeQI6o7hsIsjRnINy8LRAH@RyaTaXczhS@AKqn02zDkcXX8Ixlo2mHA6RhKRBdAMQqY9v2QiL@6AcMr6kk7kcYhjgSyCGOByOoRVivSirlyiAqfgSDCIC2uF4WqNjAblmURQjsUzrhWVTaYdjYpEXgz@AS1pvIUJsFl8wACPlrJA0hDkc56tI0KI5HFULzk7qYpXfZNLhyFsvySSiKJDMh61MXeJLklwQSYc3kF6HoweOng7mp8PRASfKsMMhgEtY8OA3AhfuG1BN3uFYWPnAnDgccwLNC0OH43HlD@kAPRcXfN/sij3rWujWU4CgPATJ80k21zk/7/R6HX2RzJ5XSVChcMEPFhO90@vYETuPcGkYC4KGo8XLS8Sgx0de2R90CUHqi6DHxaNIKHzkn4Ay@@phQqPHAgYVIGjfkKONEK4RAHfwSo3gmeI7VtDqIkHkOe90HCcgtBRWH3rhcn8mAy0u2pCXImgdF@udQO8//HESc0SijuMjeDo@OoLgnLto1gm9LIfz3uFw38UfPjqiYcex8@NHn/Nb7iPtiMYdx45o1EG7T3TRnOgqHTh5xnSWCfYEn094zBnNe/GOhxK5P9twnZNn1MDQxfv85Fp6Epx36f6IhLmgExlyuI@B0JNnhjnF6o/VFZ70SmuTSSaAizl8oMrpNYClJ9b1nPb5QI/T8APjB8PHCSvPLkfchV1SICgev3eQTqQ1/O9yOqMBp9PtPAEkH8hBZLRFJ9JO6FvlHtU85D4ecKwy74r7oG9N@@JA@Sta9OGxYfI6TgSRpI5pRyTuQG88YC3@qhn55PVx3uOjTvj07O@8uv6bv7Pv2u@LF2U1dBGOOnimurj5PxSnT7BL/pl6/vx8erZK9ZJeLHiPb/X6LU33PIfUoRN54AzuDjwlE8leNbnqayfT1IEvqIW0g8PDQ@rgtH7mCDrK/sf1qNoZQ8Zl73HQFgc5/fePpx88f6MhN5//7NNqdBlIZyhdxJWRXTzD2hr6ioWxUHq0ceD5G16QCJUAnNQJjlg4DrD2CYo2weF8@t7K0OmPB2RojK58liYqmRo/vsKJUBd/XCMnstw9gNz8WJKVz7Gg74xMJaFcPxPBEMpkwJ86UDXbCXyEXrcpzk2oBuGwA6UOimxci38X/S723VWj3CjnPrHHseMYYfr9vS0rXs7JOUkxPn6C1k6uZqkD@gctzP2oFk4OjsfOYMgZXJfcfeLAYhMXdR@cBaJ@g18cPNgLwl0h8HywJggD3EFr95rtvEzJCDx1ELv6HrsfqyOU5QBxMQxNHz6fPsP/2fPd6enzKS6tggf@W7fnZyuc/CNpqxfy2Fw7cBuYTfjfTJD8jwcPP/pOrf9TvKXLFhMckbDDffB94gyK1/ju8bvHA1AzcdoRIIXiYawxjjEeYY/XkUr@ROMI/77beBxB9KP1m3h6ZNDhM@iTgB/DMPfu6wBYNPF4JBY5oH4HDHtneQuErud7JVHUjclo34RvUpeveJwMV9eTvuC4mizxpMZPq3OyV6YPjbYPrmhA42fbz7aHtrzI8fK7fguDweW36AvWMx5ETr51QEuoZ104CGiSZZT0Ee4hwl0Gbuoz9Q3gmggmWbkLtxOK@gaXkOKrawXnpb81TDd2s1g39c03dqthmH7DfETkGMn29HEn1DOF7OG7XYMm51TiuLW1NYHHBZna2NppqyxoK5JBWj/LiiO7CjDdLYKPaMmiAnJzRJMUCeWYOSv5byywzkRCUnL5YhbiQHdNIms67NgOvYOnuJLsfZDcduI0C16IBcEJpwg4AgI68HQR3O4R7n8QXATSQ3MYLpG1IQAFRq2XUOKlJTviHb4@QHREL4GuMgCxlbrLygF99Ggna@dh1RhjJoCFmDvS2pFGW@8JXrv08ASquwc3/Xm1ytqFodBfDmyWgdu4oDCsLzCQiMKoa59ImdiwmWDjHrxQtCfWal3XGs722TDqmToyvaMTq6jGJ9SlS3B/xrUDJz@Ovv1W@G58N3o4cY8SJj49nhE0vUOXbIEcmYlRAsRjfCc/nJh3Ho/8kBi5L134jge/sgAsWcw23HbeIOdqAmjB9UWG27u8U30/qg/e3J3qAZIn3qPbxNLLJ1jvHH4y2C2K9ynB2fmANM3E0qOe8Kfww2UMOyuhwf7w8Cc7Xhhl6FISyzv@IQH8UCCix5ODzACdxp3i8Ty4IXEFAl9HPFG@/Zb3KGfzE8XncyPUd8GPuTsTHA@eBL4fu/jT@cfl3QTiH7vgmYBkFDcQD/FsXj@vaQf6ToDHVpluSLdonCN5cyBvlEgc3X48uj1KfPiwvJv7Rg9ei/3H7EYakPg5En@ytdLcdXTrpl@whAznuxy/kI9/4Qfl6PDKHg8w2TveimlReHQLIWOPZ0X1M@pLci78aokMSpi9Oto64pKcbUdWvJHTRg1yoK3ZxX0iEDdpCLJsg1sbfMYy9KR53EfmJae98gQCw@wPVWDg/fzjR2qVtL0gF1JG5dIRaR575OSYch3nFshHT6wtc1/Sr/vU8ErnrvuhtfxtloY@bzCyVV2JaiIVztCFOwRBNfCZfT6xNJa1DBuUDdEeAEO0B8L5UIsgk2w9YUMm7EAorVUBQSzUE5K13ROPRjRQP6GFvK75oEIsMqAy7yFD9g4SRDeBPMngouVTkh44oKpQ30AmkAbMg/xAn4Eio7/9lrZfTxPQjY9iW4BgCDfwcAj0ilJI/CsoBRxI5QBkFPUhSQRo@wZDcJvBTkKhv11C9i4hF0TwDLzWZiE/2SzkmqiGtUcO@ea2yMCy@OabgScRsgmCf9L1gPgQ9vy7A7u5P6bT5atKo56tXiVrcIeeU2z7QOfVRxNeHZU@xiPQO7JKlsoLfJUT2wWBpl1gzJp4eB1@E6VLFxpFOhAoZbx41Ayw/sAamYMG9XiNSTTIMZ6GX9N7zEweyszuF5jw8xVkVT753pNvdfIzkkMaZ2Wzc2@zcc/A0TBozO3zMXYOWR6JhmGfAO9bfVWHbFAmexhHuBUPaqF9YjxZ8Lhas0VWCOL0l5esO9Xlnkw@ldK3EOzEJycDm1Z0Uj8oPOm9y5s8SjQVj7HsMc160cGtHIGVI7hyhFaO8MoRWTmiK0ds5YjbDm6FmbMwQzc3GIxsnNGNM7ZxxtfOELtxbjCEAhtncOMMbZzhjXOTWmidWiRG8NIHK26SqivqGMaFYqsw3HkLXRr0DAMa7qVnCAgNvIKE6KFXnpBebNczGmfthPJMGYECgcjmHbTPCjbhsqjyWnR4rZStN9sT2irK6rwRgc3qOmil7Bw/bQFC5z6mcScSRYHapQVF5MEYEE2wUhI5kH/RfWzt0NUXx5vdSIghwa3fITqeGw1xOPKVFkt89gQH9gVb2AJ7sVlbnOk1Y7a2ctlEWlQe77S0FsbQjt821g@oYJGjb0AELAgsg929X6s06/pkb5LB95PcQbg3yVdEWXjD@2Ihb1wEeWIVlbT/BFtilZ5lp4iktMEMsL/JRWTgRYHiVu3EZ@7Y8dtf/@n/Sv/213/8F/RPf/4X/8@//Z/Q/W/w9r@BzUIH1gC//GO8/TO8/RO8/Tne/mQrEoEPHjt@@tPfwOv/@C/pn37/j62gf/yXDm9ojQhC0GsT81d/D29/H2//h8MbXgP@6g8tQIzi8D5TO6aVC6B@@e9pGlJDLGtkf/pXNO3wgIHhsiXvzqrjD1sbOy0EazbcEdfDy3Drjl80AB6zbo8D8Npv3ObNgwXg3kKu8/iRqU3dA3PG2iaAWlrghT5u3rO9NAPtHwFNGM3w90DeZl0weuxBDCfk/u/Sx7TTgzBuXEjZxT4O0eF2/u18OzahCOtxMEAdnvluoyLfe1hTAt1bCuSb9AQWhh@7LaRHylkyYvO3hB@xWzUgjpVkkePvKTutVWzo9ND2p4DI9xBWXV0UWmyGrB3e5DMAlL27jNtKcEfdvCg2SOWlD3QZN3s@t6MSD3E0hiKBaGt@I2PxhXDB@xLdpuTsapMt515UGLw6YGIOtzXSOqEE7XB8ARY5bcO70eIK7sJb9NoAd@xx8GFnB@k@YMfNzY2D2vJjUYb0rotg2MqUpTLWQdxuUGArKLAVBDRbOImuCQcCL2ggDQfqxd3d0la0LRW1G20jXFhzVuWAZEBf0Brm9ErKxOgnXqMmGnlX2b1GvoWSe0jY9eReJTrnjHa4X0UAnLtxEi/Lcj9q9hXM64LaHxO5veOzU1pvY9qJs1UpCPeol1xalxwX31dyuwm@g5p78HxlQgH2b5mQ7ysTioS/nNDLYsW4O@jf5u@X1c5KTaw1/AaZVfEPdhoobBr/FERvo46QYp04XW7o8iTtLk9nptGuPd98An9mdbbczoee9K0T57ATU9JM0Roe@DTWoMuhoRW89aXIfZ@ItT/M2FM1XTS2d4bL1t451YlnEwhaT4VWzYtn3Mn2V8xwft46hWa3XVm3bLYVmrY@PomoLUah5fn4KKuy@fgIxqciuTcMxFe/gBuanBR@tRJcW/Fda9O2PHZpeFan6f4yTmLvWtHqsjB0lcd2oBMSSdLQoRNEBTpfdB@/Z2NoFkswi9YXbsAi7ZguNzKxr420nqhqeCwDxn6BPr/BjQTx4zGhxUvzXlrYosjuRLsEL@@2o17@7Kj0ZQC/yLSKH9hFsMMML62/5DFyVt@T3OObyVnRVunVfj69tW16a@/TK8m6Yb6kmXjiaA8@f17SQdcGAwBuyAh@mQyvfRLLK3J2SFl747fUrAhfTWJXNARo/pDSJIAmbXC/BPLhXb8Z8LYmvPkW/98vwFX07NcWHzFmawvQNyPy6SPSRTPIOVSqILoAPO9G3fM6ubVoZ74yLbujQ3p4XtpBFJeK@@KgYo7HoorfFrKuFeIvyDwuHHol92Q1UcIK3EOTPvXSw8DbRZR57IoKvxC7LhvSu4V3leOqyHeJvvq6jKOiI0pPsz6g52K93I4pRvYvE6DjN0SG907d7rfFygKR19JDJuMIhfm3@UcG7l6qZhwETVhzIJoOGvSAHHFEDpYaL8YL68wDxfpwr61HrfbHKskSHgXxRYYAH6yPaHHeTbLu99Rn1bXO0le0CGtY/26WcVvzCiNuLH5dhj@PRV/OKRllWEdKrEp5xzp5q8Tl90p8SypWMmlZJV8nkl8Suq@WuS1Rs5BtVFj65zUhrzCneUURBNc2Rsvn3RLT1Fc6Af2wxDT1jVblcY9CXcckms7Eb40kLPvCTcngzMNzCs8mPBEh9EEfLYFa5Q3t2tWQFwkZ8eMtq8X2uRPQFt3iont7HnELilq5cSD3eZ2m8Gaawqs0hZ001zVgN8ktIErYSdIuBSye94pAESXzDe2MQdhzh8d7ahsuVeN1nHv97JSdx7KXdk6dx6CQnaLzOOsCpezsOo8zxGE4j2vEMXQeX4JjU7ecPziPV9UCAXR4JY5P6G@rcHwXnMdpl/uZIp9rX6Xrdx6vyxRgPlqvhCPP1vBqx57119ajqiJ@HRGNSi@NEmPAQ8Ns3T14yY@FfwJqnxsIgR8SdOCIAGMHZKfR2GoxrHSg2fCTz0G79jUfx6uhKXt8YzOGAuGexNagCkrJhOgj54FzVxlZhGEoGXyEJxCIevN4P0U096pn9iVy7NRl/C4lMHs3fcI9P7EHui4SfgfA24M4yib@qrx2UVgF@HV0YuS36HxFzio5QhEuBnDvIQuZ@r3znUxhWb84g84q/e0Sej1GgIXoW4FYpUTQbul0sOHQNiWJjbXxrpCQUJztk7fj4GVXSpTeF9GIVrBr5hvBxNvOGSqG7crvfi87W/GQtB0VhIF37INVy9btAtHFGLTRdVuWqlX5gIQtndMlh8KIKLYZ20ngLHXjJW3FW83QKq6VJNFcu2oSIvtxz@mEN63UN/MyuBP153VfVzHBBAcaEcFWzHUqln7Vfob9rln2@8qgXjHhRQL7DOv9Telr8/rdVvYF5com2dcFiIFeOuPeaxytU9iwHHoHW5b5e7L2ysTHT9BZRr6V6Br7C2t/xbZ1n@ALfHvZt7BwoZWgT3c9hzgwOwy8zajXFoky9a@MFj@mZOOxMr6mdJO192m1Mr6viDEE22h4/OwC1ncLeLvwEB/JgP6C5VYtx@@Lk3mKdd0mX6TezFxYsw4arhJbn6i45QnqnqxfWy/RAo/yYzVTLhXb0OhGo1H366kIrLUQd9OOU@9OE6y7LQEvHoplfVBaw5U0uvnhXnW8XlJGPMAY4Mm8jSV@dh1327psS5@/qLsQz4Ld4qiNa7ipBvyOVkJTh8cmW7b5an3@wHXE20hW5i3w20t6azhrhNKBEzqPj6T5enzExTmPj3YrhkWznkb63YH9BcTAZr0GdbC7molYXMark2dwAGAysr4AbQ/A2WfKWOtQDvBj1eYq9jrWRDXl1WIHHB@yPzhtzeW7ghyOTuSltQ@hAxdluAIh7MIGwriF34qF0DjwSZZW2ul8sAwdPFrZGGsqORyTHDhGzHY86NlYDb0SsifqjCfLQKxUyMkDWxRZC7JW82LWZ65VcmgwxMU9YmQIecUbLy32/GTGJxCHLsdQHltnJq6XfhhuEokQTNZoAY87ijgCkmogu3tGk69kKJV@Tu71QJAY@5se1gKXOg9RfZrkS6/OAjqgm7wid1en0tprwsiJ0PY4MLDTtXOYk0EHImBNxb3A2c0PGIvLZGg8sIkli7QIFPyi8Ihazph3K@4H18K9@@RWlxvxfXA9Yslam0NlHb/fMeXVLT7be0a3hqbtSUuiB7ZmLlfnklH2OXIJMk/pxzVqY5fjwLE6rQ2d1rIJXhFWxxy58ICtY@oblSgeXAFGC9baGjBwVTTayPSae70kVaV/QQcD5JvEkB6xUkmygMOa2dvBDmEQFYm1VvfZCsbxi67jFziZSH1zgLrQkjWMvxJldJPzaTeyTH@w0VkTKliVrSqweglvvQShq/HNnoQ/uBwewOJxuB07mADenv34xtK8r6OCUnT/jql3I62clkwm6yNOr54ne8l@stqG9xRb9LQGoSzDZC@UbjKT7yzOtWh9KgXYevs61Ql6KtHufCxfjNIX4ywlh9ojz21wHr8ILcPpYDopsDfSeVEKRdM30o0hJhUxzkwHw@uuWB13ON2QL0tXpeqSyTWum73rgXTbag2iao0aV29Tveu5eB1rqdNmI543rsVmumQOSwNzwi3K0VakMVONVLOe6hcW@dlwno9obTmcvhajTWl8MRMW4bFw0aBup/V@pHaxGMa5UXeRTBvddtTjYdrpVC92IXRvpUItfdnt6eFOeFiL88HpqCCNF/3LC/WpOEjXpoJnPMjlI1NKreSnMzHUGnaUC/W22mx2MqnKbMgZt@PuINS6mpidmB4JBidJsT8IhfMTU48VU8nLqJlJ5ps55aZp3i6asQplXpj1aKMgxBXPtGwKwUmmwRhsc16QL2uzyEWgrl2oBSU/qAzPJ@cVZTwZZkJyuT4K6b2bXEcLBC6ua9OLdpHSQ4VWO1YdBGIZYS4wl2FNGwXr8VJRv5pPUk9lsZUWaimxE2FT4ZssN7gqL4TytFittirjVmMUNS455TbHDqjyjVBLpoa54ijG1UuLfOw8X5uk0/n5tBOQelpy0m0Fr24is2JJzLeumeAFPzGvPHK6rDCDQsFYNBuX@ZuScQvV@qogh6TFPNVM6dJTJm1cVYtMSR/2a6GB2h03o3JaEwqVfMjMD5MXs9ZtPJ8ailKlM9SG9ZbSmphyZsDkqEV6eN3oiLOcvJzx2VCxec0MslXBjCZ7wRozkKTOUCkby955cdmrTTq9brx8zmbEp8tuqhmuZsfcVc4IldQF1a6nJHlZvZa4YSV@kb/tZJPylRpOV8Rx5fxiOg8E2rJUmYWX3PxmkAvJcyHEFsupmyvPdSFQ9RQ9qVRFC5Z7VCCTO2/1wpceLScumaLEP0XTHn0yCc0zk4msi8WGquijsMLGcnVPP2rorfjV1axj5G@q6ZagLGO3V8Nh5LZK3UzzhqYHYoVcMs5Uhqx@zg9K@duorOZCs9S5ko3nW8tGzMwWJ0rsotjLFKp6pj4SbuLZXm2xGPZiBbFSHCYpMZapVgedXrMzb9eMyoK9CgmDjid7ni099aAeN2u5QKGRivQm1WDzMqNOK/WcZ6ndtIrjdGnIZSuxSaQeDY6o6bwQS9ZMVR5nzq/ikeuJXMwmM71GmtNE8eZJuOSGfK2@YGNGVL/O3VyPDY9Z72ihTj8VXFxftZnmrWGEL2Tqdt6K5JNDXbjszs2CEa2rAa18zXLXUqmhhKct@ald0QbJEXPZuFkyndkyN6@YglkbauFuNDw8nxtP@vJSv6Ri7QGvNEpprTgQIpdteRllwpxab6elK6FdCLDJRu/iSsxdTHvLhjgKDC6eJhcCLxiVZLtzrkSm87FHCsamRapeat30ok9PbEcsteNyctioVvJmoM4zk3atGH4qtg0jJzTyciokq5NMqn0@HKVvF3zdmC8n9UhHkRYVPcBmqXmpfdUUBlrPyBm3wmB5k7tVryaByE15IEXN7pAbyVyxKbHR0rjqyXgqynmnt4g0J@JUAMtwfJ0fc6nkYFCmytwoOk0t4oapnhuXpU66kJSTyWIscD0ORC@G6fOLeVduNpqliy6vhW476WCk3OmxgW6qlO1VQqNetFKKhoppqt5ZXFe5biYmc31eSQ8Ki9A4XgykIkxzVr24HtT7aklJJ1tzKRUU6tos2uIltSEuI1HmivUM@vGCmmRDlQjVMDNmo5ibBT3qZf4qUFkshJsOPwny0lPb8AjtZX9Zboq8pvSLT1Wu3pwU0/Jg0IykhDpbTtXYydKY8eNihYpnKiqXKc6nuVm/1mKNceZiHOvMS910pSJ2xt3gWOqUk3OJnbZat9fXjbI6urkeXVSjnfKyyw/CTVOqRspzk3oCk6c5LTZynXlGMqRBdfqkns8nN00m1DgfFRvdqWcQv21Pg/JNmS2WUk2Jn@Sve1GzUZqPrwqKpDCjQLnHULNGZbk0xaSWLc2u2nOpuVwm5ZTxxM0vGb54ns/cmJ54NpfMlOs1XlfK5fNiJsmPZlez4k3UIy5rV92wPHy6pSqqqgT025oSTbFBI9AIZ5ZpYXDOTs5To3qhHufGXOOieXV1yfUVYSRE2@VMpHUltJLJwuWiIPHNSmVcuWzUqbJHvbm9rTPlulKMS8V8ta6F81P9qtWK8jMtec2z@dCoMyvOU7OryaQ1ihc8bVPkg9pSFLnqTCky4gXITowSJ9NKulQxFoGn5eCpN81oN814cnweSaYXUncqTpdsMjP1MEZuPutG5HEsUG/Pz6W2cNXrXVZT/eB4Oq5H0mGqEJeu1GYn3b@KL8TLi2IzNzHFWrcTkj0GOx7Ur5MNoyEs5HMh0p82jLYClU8ah@updNxQbjOxS132sDEhRQmtK77CFPvhm1Khq83S86vmIgNdjhgnVdiwtlCbk9hQvbg0Upetp8tYrNfoXAwh4Un/ti/IDU@q2xGvJaVE3d5cNofZyqTJDK5vrqKVxoUntgzq50@C1j/n44v6ssyyohTvTfOTeXBcFGLnscuyoBTmpWpDEnuRWuBaOVeXVEaN9tmkxM2mM5XxLMKpWLYnpRolVc80hIuoqFV4hpm3bs1y6yZ2GThnr9naaMYGjKsZw0ptVV60S@12oEulpsbluFXjplnPhZls1wZV4VxhSq1qfqktitmA0UiW0tLlZLYYFxeyHrwViudppSLIHJgl4UivrjeGy9S0Q7WkeTGdikVvAxcgQYahxGftEC8Kxrg3HzDFq8mFMh9Mhk3dM5ozVc9tex6O95t9gxGKxXopP8vqYa1gDFQqEhECFy19HDWqT6NFPm1m@s2GEkrHm71O@aLNXNWly/h1unYbFcMVJv8kxlu1CCsUwy2B4araaGpCiyT0hlRxwXZ1QRF1PjopP4Wzk4mnu5hOTM/4Nnp@GWv1hmluKvCeYLKjPfHzZkFh5VJU7Bnl1mx6k2uBhag2pw2Vyt02xsFL@UKqXTTLV0OukqwuTSYVbwk3oV5b5yRVmlaDZriQF3tRQcpkb4eDzEX@Kc@2pSd2xin69XUwd8FRUcmTMrWuwjSvx9fqMsCLyXY5djXrLtOjfkkSL/KBjN6uRrq1S17JQjMqPxXZcTN3XrztdpQ@I2lquVZlWeo2Esi2bqpP3LR7XVnWtfmF3iskK0rwRsqrWuWmyWWudaYUTeWu04PqbXoRi1R0pSPWe7G6OvKcBzWBT6rFCBUVp2Kq2WIaohzkovNlhx@KDHfbGg5jF8wyYiyZpGrMBrHeMt45H3Gt25J2Xl8MmfPR/LaSuuEmoofjKsKYujaXlfD5ectzuThv5HtKIy8JDD9aDIyL1EQszDrXkaQnNmbrnmy32Z8XK71xK8tEO50YVwsGWyHzqVtZGNclqpkpXgSjmYU5l7LDSWkeuxgnI7XFvHEdCg1vB/NyrBaphufcVBtmU@NcL8xoN0ZUndcvermUmJWuJONq2RFGVGQ5KeVzsawnLPLtSvuWlbLMU62rmP2eVL@8CdYijBC@KFdmt7eZJDOKSoNsXjmHNnHGX80XtUF72LkuG0GZ0sptTz6yjCxrt9elrlppFa76nVkvGq3oF81BfLJsj6ty1TNeNvId7TxTGSmZ5Q0IXKQaDw8aSrbRkm8yVbZMmZFWcgY2OJcqyosekw@zl5LKFuaj8/jNqBUZtofN9LTang8HkVo0rE3EZdRsPYUnYiPaLoxqjNBpz/qewDml1ZaLm@x1SC@WZuOiWdHESzYWKN4OG6PspOEZpS9zHTPdYsedQKs4m3jSYbAKYlfNeKDUuRyk8sPza@PiOhCn6jl5MYkNziPnngo0JpOBUY41lYAyZVqM0pxNxeGI5UsZvqnPO41csVvqBmLM2CNHZ@Zl5KnQrtzy5jikMpSxiHRnvOciCxZERm6Ha56mOWZH0Bdhb6bBS7UXDBjqTa0mmGktOmwE42IopzdVrTnXBs2AfH0eHc4E@XJApcRlN6Q0qq1uab6cdePDUJevTRvJ3I3aCqbVcX9u6Fwkfhlo8k@VkR4sm@NKsSGk1OsRz0szz1xJZa702pTq9krJbiv3NJGmzVA5GUoubrpsaHI7HXDq8ibbDgwqnWRfmlVboWV1Fkx1zzm1OpLHIz3AsPWmmh3G5o0L8ZIqLLPioh@7TlWaocblID4MKr1hrcIuhmVZEm5vjQmXb/eK11w3H26mruPDC8lIitFGXCoMmHmpU76NpLtiiKU8/fyICaSLQrCQvfGYBUEJP8lLrmQu45K6KDXkTq03TY6L3UFjUkpdMCkuMD2fl0fBiyoTnPCpUSxzqbd1hRKz4eS8Ub6KGP3bpNkMaZXANDa@rci9m0C30ueFERuJgQ6@6nZuF41kNTUrtksXNSOp9paiR59dquf5XC6lUhdSq/RkPPGaNEmGGuVi@/rpOqn36uGOaeS5@ZPILBZquZAWhEU7mTeGpWahpuaj7Kibuope97tFtaFV5OAlJcSjw5soo9aEwoQVQ5VkKPfUPBee8tNIVRuqplDP3nJmqQrKLh9ulMft2WiZ7rPSPBjK3hjlXnd8C7V1sKQCk4tqu1uVBup8Vi2YzcvgqMYNmzNlGFH5sSeUjZfLPNcLYicsfKOpI0257Jk3tdL0UmeY/jIyEcfn4qVMFQPjXjJfjRQC/Pl5OxNvcKOnohiIXYUmyVmgXL3yqGFxnMn3RgqbHlYH4rUMXYZWpDIosLWS3OjdTtI38UWNWrY7UlwttGbaZXo4ywyng3pjHoTuVb1ZNIxa9cbs5qeBTiGqdMr9bj2TS18LaZ43omU1nS0Px5NmZzS7CIWpQS54M7iKFuReZBjNi4v25WQcrxSW@XT/IuRpq4WY2eZN5amsDJ5KHdPsPEXlZu26wLRSUUFlnxZR86bfYgzqIjbKnofE6DLf56INdTSdTLrlqqrlF5XrK2BzNBCsn3eY5Lh1XTGb3QtRuLlogKVf0MR87aYwrp3fXHQnXZVSgiC@aUa/PC8auZvM8Jab5auLjsx5huXLWTkcDUvxjmcaHpX6k0w43IqOCqVpLjPWI/Mr0Pq9yqJSFKulK4obXbWzQ09B4riYfrVsTkPVpHgT6VzNpFkonEnO1X4s1mDn14Vz4TrWGedno0aB610zs9v40BjxDb6aFDSpTKWexsFFZm5m2XD2MnJxcy0OIrNudhLIJ2e1Vj5ixktSqxV6mlVnQ7GU46T6fDoLVHLla1MNhefN69vhJZRCmBJ68@tsVLwKiV1WXt6m9ZzWURt8kmUKTGDWaF57tJ76VBI9w0ogFxxHsuy8wkPP@DY1KXQjncZAaZ2nLuJ9qhsSsp66EcnfRp5unq5k/WbgiY5A5cSk6vT6CkySjtmoh@bXUrzNLZvpWIvv5JZc9pJJhi4uJvF8IFAoxottyqiFRyAtT7PATSGjBK4rzXpo4smUMvNuv3bbqKZnV7HbNjeqtGrTAnbGggw7k8qDamNRys0bshjJDqtZKUV58tczoxwfS9VMM6szla6UCw2GF@e5c3FyKUzmWdXD9vKNxfRpMhJjhSuFF3U1VzX7SSHYjg2DcyE/Tj5dNqnFBZ8tcOlYM6YPZaEwKDWMgTFtjSU5GXoKzz1mdVCRL8OZav1GHTT6pZIupK8CUUPMDGujyG1jMO9MxWy3QElmfCoo8/NSxFRTi5x807i6LnRr7EKoxAqlnD5nO0zuqcZOTaYRq1XqvU5Jl4sDaDg97YamxRRQKWZfu6b4cT/PzprJy26sZ6TP2VixMC835JKHvc5WB5mAMdU9TH9UDmSWWrYQlGbRXvX6csTq6Wm377msRJnbQUqblaiw2Q22eGMYr0pcu91kxtnq0jCuYo2O5/JaYcRq4Daaulhy9U5w3J3027H26Hz61G5fPXWatQsozhuPGKldPVG968sLIyrFBa7bSKWLSW06Zgv6qCqFRkWt3Qi0JU97nsnPngKXbG6Q73ClUn@5TAkFvaXGMqPOVZpfDBqxJhXMltnubVAcFxqZp3auPxkI6eJcCN5oF4bnJlSaT871WDTCheJT3gg2R6OmJ5ZUZE802F/0A6nsNJJhunq1RWXLnnRL06AWVG8jfIkxQt2SYhqNaL2WjVfTufRF8TJ7IxXjtTx/c@NpX@fT2WQ9UrjsD0OXbc5IMamr/qAWoAbF9LDLmGZsItfknJE91zPz/u3wejTpzKLTotFeqpf8RO6NOIkfD1tFNRpJXjefwmU2mL1isrdLRQ1Ew/M41RWkboFRqsObVkzOXjBtpQ8d6AzI//DmaqILkm704y3I@dVSjaYb5V5Tv1D6FaBQ6UzGgjSKy8O@GLylqkwtlou2lEtJKLero2i7I9/UC8GoNJlD/7WdWV5KGQZKvdGu9SfsTSQLpmso9JRv9UfX01LTqIYzzXqxEqKaT9WMxOWzxWLz1uxypTLby03NRjR2keWEUWpYyi5SnVR@lhMarQvPwBOod4VprplUss0ub8wXt2yc1ZPSgIoMIlcpKcOZs3BT0kPpQr8c5JW8Ni8XYuNRtVIIpArZa0kb6mzqOrm6Is1FfCSHFz0pmTxv5tvpHpW8TmcGgaZkCFXVM8sTsFRO4X/3s48KEXVdJWDUVJO7@OkqQ7SPuTh55@AJcvIEbm/fOXcCF/tsHyQg2furrS/seh0N3CF8bCVC5jb9@FkTnFo8eTm36ONWxwmQB57jQR@RT5lIOxOhDh0jr8n4IKvvEUBmPMkMCs6Dke3JvzCO4Qc0eFcogU1kR52L8Mb9RdoIR/CcDzxQlH042ZrydHHb1CCBUGS8KgE/vY5f4KkK30JEMgWcLefc@6b12ZOd@ECcMVbJSSMOn99BotqnYiCmXRRWaaL/@mwGihzIsppYe@dDbTzDxdhInJzvQate0zu6i/@/xV3rVhtJkv5NPUUibCMZXbHd3YOAbgHC1iy3QcJuH0zjklSCaksqtUoC1DY/dn/sC@wD7MPNg/TGF5GZVaUL0D17zkyfMaW8REZGRkZGRmZGXGRftrZSyhv5br8Xjoe37S9XwfVNR3XV4NfmXWvy@29KvXmt4NFo/YU4Gy19t1VgT8/fs9/Mv7Fz6GfG1ye73YenL/bbCNeiq0pZN1flZZXhjyz@2UiVZ7hUvewZLhQnH73z7y62@lvFcu@8f1Hur61lRmtbo7XSWhoJL0qZ8mCsbyKejy741X7hpTo0T@sRxgR3f4OOOgn6retgNVR3Va@VeHPCHs3MBOq5g/h8uvFao2AYT@mAn9xeYiLOJuGU2J2q6Qem3Ggy8HB0Z70SdAPiX/yzNP7udXk2Hz1cWoILjbK@OxHvwFdnMG52/daGs8T0xBE4ntNvbGinMC0Fvl1a4jRfEgUX5YdpZJdNbisYTHRlX4pcmr5sxkBup3G2msk@paQp1SSevETQuSEVkyJC3kRxRaD5aDQjWOH7wOvbc1D48cmU4eVELZs84/EH5cE37HfncqR89tJDfzaVLso@MFRGe5zg1HMfj974KsH2qmQt/TruDfj8OS/4aoogou7lwPWHtmY@HDfxuleVQAzfII0RwMc9PMLduCMvPjRmLHDxjR9foT@Ad8JhkQjhlotw5yQb8fgA8NoB11mSkM1pNQrkYqWgoetyNzJ6qIlw8MO@OljdUHwPrkxJfCRajuX@Srno64LsHmX33NH1guxrwB6Hi7KHlI1AzguyfcqWN5Hz8wPKl5P@BQVGuOVJ7Ho5Ci5Hrt9Ni0MPuAK5F4GdVmtrhrCWBZQMjIxHsr7SrlHUsoyOMFuCvWh@MltJAbB0Wk8e/I64hXPhpj4tfBFrU2iivqpHG9OXI4nEl9wSiV20n3mZgK9iCND8I1GqZvNN4zLatqMJ/snTsnOF0SZivVLfvj2EmWbEJP@VLgz3yQjhHm6sh0KtCI7EmY3GVSr9rivNr6Ndx8Slm7kjEfXDTMr1SITI3Irmdcfvt6kNArwcT8aVp4z6MUo5Dy/UhpUeER1lWjxOx/UZ7sGNKJ6RWdWMPltPp6oLvqeaLq3IzUhYwE@YW54hZ2hL55Klt6m0peYUn7USPKNn6Z/t7NN6s0L48aRm2pRF0LZINdzWCM5Bz5VxjcsEAfZsdUPSERXXTwLzFwATf3qXBGC0SThgZTNi3KyJfj8vb1JJzhfXX2f5irkUuY/IZITVU@j0/zC5QDi9ZI8RKDApktQc0swUt/0Gvbanp9xU90TSz@/cuTxqXv1xFTiqWX5irvuRVskNVVTWcVNZ3T8uh/4aZb5Gw5fQd8L0YllhBt1w4lNY8H4BoR9lsmQX1i9UguJAgSXDI0sSOyGcvyhFV@svTYq5dilze6EGBqzKyXzgLABNBinK8VpZrXNtR6JTe1@8HBnlJhtpYYjPK1xBKnvZiYtzbOf2efGOp1rXUUyReA5eskPDHBrM/I7RbUkNNvXyrUsMsxAZ9KQ5fRUE7bRRmLTCwBCMhw4qlBV3VlatEvUyap6a00qvutJePsy6W6aUZZ3E6wolQPnUvAkkXl7xtClj2sT0Gz/k8NGcj9WImjKvD3BZUaSP2phOR2mrAi3NrWQkPnySsedKLed5JU6Ih9Su28fFUAyHbK03U0i3A4Ey27TRjvxb8hjcz7EyiA9P7d3ya3zr4pf9PHRiO@jmFmSmbLHZ3EyhGcvw93@sLBfG4bDQ9PsFr39DSnVz4qwory9xDDfUeNTJ/YCLwpXTt@@1NOF72XwJkdiERgqt5fvebRplSHOGF9FUxhGfdHxpseTALzHfG@96N23S@sVjyyAI7/jfCW0WivnxYBRwjm6Ifdepb/63yJ9qkV8R6R2DRmeT4URl0nhfIKkTuSuZK4mCVILP5UwMxDlqssBNfUqlMH5AVN8nPb9wwrzntq6BBHjvm2ynaLiYk@@d0Aw9fK2BFHi8Qp9d8TIx4LujaIK1k3DCv6n7@F3Ch6TwFVfwvd6nOHwhGDndIBiAyXEVFPU3iQBC@KV6Y696eprXEZbkxjpuucs9ZjwRZId1HK/BXuPFbXW4C5RBWUJnAVva24qAs/xlGqFZTSZMhVuQU2gFf4TSg1yJf810w5bPSHEmCT930r9C0LKovXoMSI8C7aJq6Vi1nKlmCsdIsfQoNdxWC44gDr1eQBjvet0uIS20WIrIgU9QxLS/ZtsPz9HmhUVe8nMz@blEfl7yBamoVL51PYwKbcQLpVa@RuXuVSoqlp1pa0tRp2tH7F0qHwxjeJcfKhvmaZPmR4W37VAKV9qMzURGLpbzy5zRl5zlRB3L4Db/XPI1f6/rkbdYJsr@lGwffx09QB77YNBPFqe4NN/3uz@K@dHmsIRVcKsk1THezHYyKbVBRIuTHIkJYmKetttbEZS1kpE4PGdS25s/pfLaJPVjehqNDL8QmJlYc@ZIjErc5hoT7o5XEmqHs5djIBgmGE2ZmbttKk905UkMLEotm2Yd4yk0OcGpa9NTfAvXur/hHzPZk8iZcivzM5cE8zvpvLy0SBKIhe5yaj6ZktJkNBx7kqg79cAqErU9mYY4X0gcBdiBtq4hKWybnrwH6QTjfnvZyom4oDCSYobuNkdTOipQMuy7aAiRee/8UXjpvHV7pBV2vTtVgU7tsqd@J/HYZuSFo5DmgEcdHKpwPBh0fe3XTd3ycw4dK2j9DR4jRBBjSkPeqeGBqJTP4ks/jqFKeXUMyLd4ZxhlhOMrRI@HJRiB0Em0dnwCOco7lf6EPROzG7R1efLiqTH8uEIAd2nbF0NCRk5mD1seoKXlHfOwSLrakfndH5EKRB0P2OchXK1uOM4/xn7ry@5btV4sfl8qvirFSGZM1cX8q9eqFlORTMZ6sVQsvim9dpzdYDCRp43pVgawXucAMKsOsNC/J970bhCo3KnQisEFQ1L9Q29447XzjnPqtdkG3BwzRcDKY5Crb/y8IoV0K/i7J3W3F2YVbbuuIV7wF@uz@K5tsWONrIM3RANv2PNH8tIouPHbIKB5N9UJut3glg3ReLIk9EClnjciorzMqCRK7JdW48K6C7uLJWog5gM78GsGN@xHWpOB9FQf7vf5AZADJ4qAEG@s357ChNprdV2/B3aagwC8LEUUMAhQ19rjlvcgDg4j8SdxULpj7aA1hmde14xMgaRfwHOFprs39En6RgTmUeFqMdxpgBvvanVVP95vfKicVhV9n5wev6/tVffUzkfVeFdVu8cnHzmamHp3fEDSpa4qR3uUetQ4re2cNY4pIVWpU80UZziVo4@q@vPJabVeV8enqnZ4clAjaAT@tHLUqFXrWVU72j04o8X6bVYRBHV03FAHtcNag4o1jrPcqqnmRPXU8b46rJ7uvqOflZ3aQa3xkVvcrzWO0Ng@tVZRJ5XTRm337KByqk7OTk@O61WFjjl7tfruQaV2WN3LU/vUpqq@rx41VP1d5eBgqqPHH46qp0A@0cudKmFZ2Tmockvcz73aaXW3gQ5FX7tEPELwIKvqJ9XdGj6qP1epO5XTj1kNtF79xxkVoky1VzmsvKXOOelHqELjsnt2Wj0E0kSJ@tlOvVFrnDWq6u3x8R7Tul49fV/brdbLyjk4rjPBzurVrEJUWG6aYBC1KJ@@d87qNaZb7ahBa8bZSaN2fJShQf5AhCEsK1R1jwl8fCS9JSIdn34EVNCBByCrPryrUvopaMrUqoAKdaLabiNejBokIjbi3VRH1bcHtbfVo90qso8B5kOtXs3QgNXqKEAw0e6HCjV6xr3GOBFe8knM6hjOzfJwqtq@quy9rwFzXZo4oF7T3MJk232naU5zueDMPXJ78ABv9pRPm0IedhK/e7xXJY1PAsGkovQzWnR@SB7eJfJoobGZ9FOfgvJaddn2muOrS7/fCbA1t9XkBLsXXmURZymDSL6fnAcioeuDcq6wsnJ5@b5ySfvc@uVlJvuUmgk0HquhvbA@VCqj@9gN3DZv8xO2pTihtl9oX@9Zcbwct7W8sMaHjCoU2p6uhseLAGzMRDooAQFrQzLyq0a3r2JN8hFz0lbEETOmjUXmeDMI6Z/@t@iHrA2xBBLOcm@hUMAeltFA5BNl8adGOCiIjgzC9wD8DjeZDz3vy1W6GG8OW35toMqYOlx2RNvAq3TmkepN72qqem66PiOLt6asrBh38MZNOxgz4F@aZEqPS37IPUuLaY//ZAw23BAphRlpih@y6tsn6RdSHf5FxVaYKVtX4hwO5LDyc@0DNnPF9dflqfR3Nl3mFl6dI7YNrXfnXO@C/7y7kAI0wXxsv4gk/kSOVAuFWB3SyliftIXhq/4ahW79Nq2pWKqvPV7W4SFf3AXH69NiPPTv4tiTGH57WjncOdvfJ8kJbF//8Ob778qO9rg/HP2clb8f0Q5CbjJ1SYu@9UlN46zYLNklvWd/JlhOLLoPRg8FEYLSDBonuqTSWs@ZoiNIfA0xA6G7ISIM9BFkI4UgAcOUwvt8b9kx/Dp3ZmoGSCe6mkFveu4da/guqUrMAy3xktmd8Kjd4R/AttPfTHHbIc1AmsW83mA0Ic6lzQXLvdS@cTjAext@Vowi@ZTh44Fr7iAJYSAz2QsD3uDzL83bsVEkvRYDjfnKw841CYnlaSxMkBYOuURNnAShmcGS6FPKz5rf6POjDg6ELIR6qIzqRMZ9WzNngveIzVlPDA35YnuLhujFC9vSpoIhNaOREvt/MnRMfDYwKnKhQU0BNjePLJ1tDhuhf1rNqK/CqfDqDThlzbH6N3HuvO5oKGXjEl3/NhFklMCKAspw0q1twzFFPpoilpwJMv1L9GD4/0aazIG/SRtOgh5Ri@Ww3x97T6QkQxVa0e6VieLfmhtjsWtqETXjSR8jMPfxgbm2HdPX8O7kYIlIoEdnYhI@Skix9BwCgMlh14jPXzjw5Ul87dLO6Seeu0ty0j/st3qDtAnIZZaKGbgXWda5suaKHH5k5Ai/qGLNHSC@yk/s55FlBjZcJMWaE/U8TAmMtRLLHHS68JKNHnaWM2uCDCUzwyN2KuqpZSb/nb5hFK0ybZN7T6ro4mBf9jgEMYUSAt@cgBgBwnef4h3WZKM2t4Ho3H7D0wtb@ZVexRH9kkQgr8uqwe45QrfDe2YsRdqXBpx2oEnAed7WMZua3ugWy0VXoLMPkQiaSj9nNyZoRNsirRphhG8mT1TnRfbWYs9mSvCrxf6s/6WP6MuemLhMiXwiAlTcBWteHbocDKr7tH6nosbXQNbtZPu1PvtVacl5JUxzvHOnVrDTfx5GFCGN8xbaJa1DEZXc1hckpgyP@rc5/47@cFs53XMT04j2DByxbp7Sf79wQwBemboDq1Kf@taItCEL2dZzo77gS@au/fqIL21n3qJOEXKUgguzWg0CytCbcElzdrYxfgm3Orh8ukGa0@1tvumOe26/4/b87oRvnf4aXPcLYX8cDvKDiZNKpZLWQDgCh4sUwn3kqQ9@vx3chmqHpgMMSfWjs/pJ0vAXs3ztiuVLqb9TG2qHW3ZmwHfgMykMOiMaGq@sJjr0@TAy97CdUFta2Kw1QQIcUw2ZgajdntWM3x6dqbde3xuSPnjCdy7Vgd/y@iQ@SJniW5jhtUgaFN9H63XdutqH7sKWnbLyfDbqWNueoxvQ0LJgrTRNRUJ4qMMqwjY/IVaP2QTzsx2O@tU2RqXrYKC9AcFoCmVTTJydcTfrIHbjh1rjHTbjsjFn2wwta8bWB1uiqE49MdZSZ4ZufzQhojjTxhtC@zHbTV6xMyCC6CwmJ2/qeoje3obZrxtSVxG3XksBXkFoqnr@DYLFsRnuKWPE92y12SyiW1n7V8xK@DojOhKj50Sjl0XM0HxWvfmbanjgXXXSdVu0w1L1Maq/ekV64E4QjlD0sKJUcb1UKuVKr2CiPatX8jwR8H8TQcxxaocnx6cNIqR2kW8Yw66ZID4H7ZLbWESOHEJ3Ue8/QyCb8iQx1z8z8aCCGz@@qbKcWKQ2UjT2LRfmXuphmFSH2SQLk3ww5MBh8AZFLJSYjtQqnB4gRB8LSbQUg57l0GU6@JgsLRZP9ubHFT4Dty7xVRfnoZ@5MqeRAPDuOI1qDXln0NZu72lMel7PYu@PzOruSgFnOuaZJZjYUok5VrOr0JKIepk4nLaHOxIhogf0wpvWkGSLe0MshyssxiUW8QzLpoztjdv0uz7NAcKrdR1gwRFxZQaCTRDxiGgOj7iNtYMFiXGZE62AZlc76NmigpXjWGdwOn0QTlqBWrmibTZ2WuHA89ocKWE8kFAAyM/TLO/SyiFu4jaiGAHOSpHvTQ5J2CAkC8m@cRe@Y@Hrrylj7pjeEFcZ94KNa2zrBRD1qD7iSYqIbek5O@yswjlvhofdJYZA3QwIscDRH4EYZHEoRVjReDND8BezSxbuqLo83tN@AFGRgxGFg2QGYMmprpfMMODRd/05U0CYdMsiMOVi0CAjfrLkO2EDS/5Af3HvFE7T0tJH6twkY4m57yOEptgGAnUV4F8UzhuKyRmhx2eEM44L7@CSl@BNlyzNlqRSNoBIrOT6HJi5uTBfzYeZ0zD1YWWtf8MO21CL2UJ6Id6gA5KPIETU/beBEb3sVq4byAGT7f1VN2gibhNJCmoNfybZaGDjybwDSxA6nitOBJPxpjZNlzTq@m2T0V3UJs0Pb1ttGovF9qe@DJTO2JK5xD7LFK9dPJ34E//oGcWfqUTwKmgdU9GrgJ6kkuwG2JQGqVNSGyqambiJEy@vW05W6SWqlKaqaOSSVZqJKutO5Kl0anRRA6Iff5M9M3oJ30riEVBbdoCKTs@9k91NkR3QsZkGISMTHvHWLzSDoOB5S1mfdih@4UQumhPH9tKG@clX8PjGd@pZikNeFZPxDu7M1T0WA1wqkT9hN@D9tO5QRpOBf1j3zxmDjO7XJlfpxySV7bBkOIluD/FWKx1vJbOhVgaunBqiVIiFLd70OdMAp/Qp@u@lSusGcnFkpRDc6mpRSIRn18vntJWVYTFysOhEKzP/igk4GkFH5DdfGZNlIJ1OzCsjuS1M@ZyR3QQK6QKOW3LE/2dIep2kYkWJiYY6FD6EMdVKnndH2zM@Y2YQvP5Yi7VOFJ/GVnpo5M@jli/MqpHsxcLS00vJvDKxVcVS4aHChtiWTgsLL15tmHSwIUDeSfEY6Q5gJNakM0vwaigkYy3FH7Gz06Dli4RKki0mdKVudo4ATg65QS471Ssn5spc93B6GXESK2eCSdKxXwjTrp5LIDsBlHEStUD/RQOO647xib2wXEnK6WFfxBEWlhn3h9jCFjbj/hBbSOHYsD/MFiaWoSUt15/mi8RICAlwKVHvGNimFJdBJuMuXupuqhQjNLmI@zL3uuk52MakqrZ1OjOqkiWRDl2SbIP/3MnArGhHowl2JOKd29G4iHpLa1zri9e2Hpl17@0WaTuVXBJkNKcDEaDTpgUeo4sMQmbbCiSxxQim98w9ubvJHu1XZcPCe1BE7bq6Tr7uTYA1q0oxM6tQGu/9EfKbc5HPzUZRiLZYG7Px4e3tMo01LjwFwzZKp5w5J77OI1itxbBK9i42QkkSL4CUexKk3BMgFWKQ9MR@Reslf64MEafOewzEp0@zMPjPL7SR0jBI0rZ9GLGxD751J4/BXCZla4Xv1Llyq8xWiPTkx2D8OA2D44Je29M4nXjtwur2uzcMpqNyLKRsklfmYGSxWplFKwu0WGrzfleXM6oS723zX5rXvt0JrDw@0uLHWFfGVeJrewi0kvSqb4FF87@0gH7Z2LAm54MgnjDDkLbs/MnpkAchxMIkT8VshZggS@5DdUaSEA/nTgs/3q1Oez9GwNOF1TKP9uQnMfjEjE4l6ppIrATHmS1cJJzMamXk27zt2aPtr8xtfxAMSMfpzEWAy/dgxxej1JRIj1TTqa31k9ayuevZbL/iettUbJKnT/IXM11fp67jYTpN6r53q1f/hyDrvpgR@Aua/LnhkQVIPp@LJA7aXW3cUv1xr@kNnadMdamRxx/ZIy3mXMdZWVGVFm2ZtWd8WMVaHL7P001CDQYjhGo8wHlNKJc7MblhI/OEgafLtoPbPpfOp9AE22h7ntvXrvL1gnk1xPmFLZtF@E487uIW/H6LCB16MfPnZ4lJ3fZ0Dm4kP0DW8vyxB1ejTY1FNmpJoyW6ZnqS3NNK6gIFx2o1XGpjWlExvIPD0JeimWt9iRTzzHwT2FO0p4cUImLiRU3qDe8U6Id5dGMxMccDS0o7NE8g5Tx1y1q5n6BuTZ6qbv0bKDk9oE7sW2sPeoHdeFSoTW/ynT8KBRuYsTfHdcv7xv5@wuFJc2J2BT1v@KZYLMIJTtMN@dQi4Q0Hp8R@UEiWLsAmXhjc/n34vllAVRxaIDLBhjnM9MKgS6ImzAfDK4lGARyoKErjaAJ8gqOJMa03sXAPsOf08Srn11BKigeetuJrnL693P6@wczHIEE8b0N9RgfRv8@qM@6LEf3WlS2DhmLum1FtqKE3KXNNjsiDhA486tgraQyM98361QIOPra2vzpLfAYuzwU5XHzma/QMMfXO63aDrPoQDLvt5ZS8Dk1W2N@PVyhKEVwllMkTcvjirPJu/G4shDOKALeg6@W7wRWDwwm4frbIb5mG3gAnaWmsY6feVfVukE6d/5IixqQur6Gbayp1gec9VylaolJ8hP44WAmYQWg/qXTPHaRbTKfpwrQG6rdU0Rdh9KqUVXW5HQx7yi51GZc50okiGfELIzR7vDSIOh/d/K@B309T15Ht4LkcP/3m4eWeLChuiZv6dFfqgIZFgaFxQoiep9W4L8Pp1F//H6zbsBzgcSPbeO2T2Ji/sXg/jDEeM0vdjDodml5iid82rsYMOBaVuRLfUgBp9MAOvd8QqyC92glXJcAKrtrUJ/1WApHz9YusWh2POj@sEoR/qY@OmYF6@hE9cW3iP3I0rffHHMc7kmdshsMFilm5gwqXqOA4z1tbv92mK5WKejZYW1OVyg595HKqslNRe0jY2VF79HsHv19srb95U5abc3uZr5S4YxLv1Q7B4CVojTYCe/ST8rawo8JWCkP8rLD1LFt@drm1uV0OC@eVnYtC4Yq@/vmf//3P//qfQkX/@F/82OEf57/YQvl8vvCs9fXZi/syfp/vXaw@a54/G1ysXpXBZf8H)

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxx8=,
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n114O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p seLz
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"--}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001884 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 7290 bytes)

The old Moorens was run on the `v2.0-dev` branch, this runs on the `master` branch.

I also have not tested this in a few of the untestable languages because I don't have my normal environment, everything on TIO and plus both versions of Moorhens work for sure.

## Explanation

The biggest trouble in making Moorhens work was Moorhens 2.
Both Moorhens and Moorhens 2 have the same tokens, but each token essentially does a random thing in each language.
In order to fix this I had to write a program to find all of the tokens I needed.

Here's what I got:

```
 command     Moorhens     Moorhens 2
 ho          increment    increment
 dO          increment    No-op
 MU          reverse      reverse
 ay          jump         No-op
```

Asside from the normal transformations that had to occur, to make the code work, this means I basically need to get rid of every token *not* part of the code. Previously some tokens could be ignored because they were helpful or did nothing, but the chances of that happening go down drastically when there are two languages involved.  So I needed to detokenize all of the things.  Most of this was the `and`s in the python code.  I had intentionally tokenized these before so it wasn't very hard to undo that.  Simply removing a space on either side works.

In the end the relevant tokens are

```
dO ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU
```

The final `MU` is impassable so anything after is meaningless.
For those of you counting at home that is 30 `ho`s and 48 `dO`s.  Since all of them are run twice that makes 60 for Moorhens 2 and 156 for Moorhens (`ho` counts towards both totals).

Answer (score 9):

## 158. [Hyper-Dimensional Brainf*ck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf), 7269 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxx8=,
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================                                               x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOx4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2
> =157;y=146--/2
>main=print y{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?" ye h m 3 ;p se do
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001842

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rb@vKlhj4@TDzD@YLt@x7JFkPknrLtry3npZsWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQoUiap5z4@6MwMOunuYCa56TRuupO@tzsZTAOTD0FmBkiQAANMvgb5EScfG4O5/@DOWkXqZcve@3RPgKEtsli1atWqVatWrXqywxv93/3uAC@6oimLnqKZtCkaJt3V5amo@@nUgv7Ey0Y4EKQohErqvclIVE3jmDqgOZqWVUHuwjttakNRlZeiDv4Bmh7rWk/nR7TZ501aNAR@LBq0NjHHE5PWpP3RgjSdHWkD2YcxR7LaAzBT1Me6aJLwEE03VIUfdbr8i5DwiwTHOoQbdEZUfhj9YNKCNhrxatcAyAhNZ8qpbDH5AkOUpq803RARjyAahoaeMZqeZ0XhBWgcQHld1orJ0vmLII6lz4F0fqyIc5rvGKbOC6asqRjE0bVSo1Z5GSNAN@u53EvfIH3p01Q6NxGGO0GkDCq61p0IyB@zL0Iw8lSSFdGgBMj7GT22S9KPDvqA1kW@a4FRkqbTGIUeDRVapoXxmO4ofN8v0IoMsDk2RotYBPQSwpW@Qc/HI9qQR4DF0EbiNi0GrYpilzbGoiBLskAooMW5KaoG5Njw0zLQPpMVhe6KCkTYkCV4ARk9Mba8LCL8VFejaLiE8YtMrN8ORYBRxRUjxDGUBDJCw4IDrqz4MdP58RiIBGbWgHBTHoH8yabToEXekFHCIYohql3Cw/Fa9jWaV7dzSU9lnuaB3olOcBuijgXqJ3jpvqiLgJJfS59rpssmsABZnKQrIq/TdV0U3bv1YCdJSEzDFEzMiJ8U4empM1vOOaEorRh@fmxSB3qwfn1B8bQ/QR8@nsAv4XCcUNlShv58eI9uS@yhuMe6i3fTiR9pg7m/F@E35zpMT3@mACsFXFFoRhubDO8bA4E@EwhkeHSiyzcN@MfKVsL06Yuy2BIwC6oLpUEXVLrpJTkTJrqOVXvDVH4ImVY0tQf8hMzqExX5odIRFopA0KBmemlxClwDkSdlpM0Ih@t9GQrNwCLZqkyWgiIMBRUFsmdzdJWuoSkTAgcxDRMFELgCURFjQaKbtMTLCkaBcERlUa2LxkQxMc5E7WLJgwISu356RYagdRFopE0hOR6QEg@oT6OtWkiIAmAoCI1kFYN@@od/1u31AE9SEDS9a4trk@5qAlGlPCEW9BONAqupvELIAjgvpm5FhwSmvCJ3eROTVxd2EoQIkupMmyhdWoME9ZkMVavPT6E6SpIomKIl5Jb29dIjfmjpDtmSXMj4iO9AwZIESNok2z76UxpKSRCpAyIzvtHElGK0b5ylnQbznevjsevjh3sRiHP73UeHDNM7AYHzHxEveHO@JznN5I52NEze0OQuNV6YfU0N0D6BdggJbSyqLucODqfXqXecbj/qNJf7RE4IfklWuy7nKcjiGSTsdJ8ICeFOPn44eRF9O0lAM0M0WF1Fl@B2UKBySKWYMiNeVv3jBd302a6tMM14RJZjsH/LGxnz0m9qeRyQ1gflUkMBAT3kNxRRHLtYP@dGNYFwe/ONAfty@gKHneFj@cHjPHB6trNOMEBOdzKKlbUua6i2lHEfGxhgimqMQX3rKLsCD9JjoBY3wQTw0h0i10T1g2YhOnEmOnWR7oAiXckRqZJWlcP4PlSUNoZNFVrB7dZosbtVoUEZQJ02jVdaWdFmkDChDdswUCEqJs73oIggspWhpJUhK0Xis5u1oQqKBbF1RDrm68hQGbDagW63ZX8rjwAeDFgwgM2qLFs6aMQvAItgtYmbikPLEtSpEagJfUELIuoeUEKi1bBgIhNSDw0wftAMYn2BcHi3rr2qaqbOJH23oKyXzLs1CjO/XalQ4dCSOKMVXu1N@B7aXypE4QVBHJu2woKcGCaopJftDvH02Y2o3@hTh59epk0aE7t53UoDlb1VenaTyKOWsS0wnwJKleZtG5LuyjqoJ2XxMnUAmL5I3PE9guwQ8L3jDRJWlgAImTgXhYkJ2g0EedaXhT7ILlKnWvrRaoxeJg9e26mDhvdJ66SRGO7s2wDlZ9ZeSMabKHxYoq/xQCOLqM52PEjhb3u8j5k3RnsQa2sSoUHY8vUzvB9k7ws4R5qq7UEKjFyjRZDdEKscwCKroTUIDdjK/CKVdW0irosIygy0B9R8kL@@aY6NY2gvZLM/6fhBUpi6viiYZRWFhTH1hWxqlrujaB1QzwbUT2aVAiNMOvL8RYaI37oMBwY1BUNMMugEtOBPE5A6l1MyQHES/zQCbwU5iAInKKy7AwAJkB8Y5ZIMopJzoFRqC1VwOfykKvmh0jm8tAMrrsMNDoy15ktaG6EWolvEQECLL6WD5pJAW9m6n6h@fm@Tt24DiH3ndPoHmqy6Pjs/fPjgPHaegYb/8OEjuE7R9RFdHnB9JC4fcSGcH10khpe4MPSOxEC/B@fz3Qrz3P2AxTbH1mkpj1383fFx8MHL33H2M4BPN6g60GwA7cMH4HG6Ewl0ut2Osxlk1N@RdnOfRu1cE3R5bDPhgp/y1rvNhSBhgzwaazoasifY2L7Pk1FCh9YQjFeh79Kd93fs/cP95/uu5/7Z6cXY7hM@0YFMQXqukb@naxNoNt13oWMf9@B23wWhsewknKzzyOWK@RRIiHe7fxFze3iL2y6nCFrbdX/vBKba/LkT@jrBN/cG3O41q4AObKDBNnQ5/Z9jkH7H/eD2OCGu2@mFrkbC6QTOCMgEg2QaJZMwKAcCmK4Vd7p6oyGoR1owFLQpfLplVsArc2R5dsljbTod0wXSsqrQXgIJ0Fx2110cVVN96oQYwsRK1bYTIp0xhCB@2HigYpR3YBCxJM/B0oeKu1hZNNgAo1GThu6epoj@FrExHDRIPo311b/XrKlY7YJfMDaFCAYMOMcKL0DN3EV376DvASEIKsPsD3GfvEL80uYh3ZMv5RFaBoFXkX9dmZjfE9noI3vBRMI@gS4BV9H2hsZdJFwr0AI02j3gtDiXTcsYB0GoYZQ8b7jcaP4lLfMJrTZs8pGoVdedtMeaAB0XEZp@DLV6gXRWncq6piKT/VlADRJ7gmXwAvk@9oIYJZOFQOZt/u5DDhx75c1t8XYb60vmCoZAM6qmaD2NPgIAFE2/3xZsqBz1/kSkRKGv0Y57aEICZzTTFacMCqQDdHUfbCEf2BuiTlrbdTR78IYytQk0211RkUeyWSCjGIqKbdNG765C01AAGwQVWTQp26DcNFc4oLFRJWrPgs/OUeMYlEiedKmcyT5WkvV8wsFMDJ1R5A7ksCs@jsCyUETDQdMHdFWE2HaE5VCpapqZIJUUx05eXwcItIIvZh6LhVQ1WW1byZB4hjyaKDwmZsHXyLtFYGF74EXStdHaijJs3h4GkZvizgAadi3s0BCGTuzhsy3/KPqPcOjLL1A9QaB9mvW69rQBYwiIw2F@YTymeh4PQpLhsbWnDRknKHGIzK93Vp6fOfYZ/dfjY1u26jbGfeFvR1oj5whyQ50Y463MfeYCxH9qShIq27V3kHgPfYAGrCzC4T3DgjZ4BGG7WkdU5pGQT1Qkvzlf@tGAiYQo60H7um9B7IlLzZf7IlAmWCO@ufQigNcpi8I6qIyiBuqhKBtkFHVbKKh1O3RPOVaN6U6b6diEBDadW9o33d8rd2wjIvIJEjXU0IbbuB6hBxpGLGsUo6HyOqYEmpTcdkBfEfU6xKoXo45EbnsAju2OHlRyHHZErlzgoBX2NTVo18QZASMmK0EG3JJVnqmSBxqv@@jZNcN3iOmI0gRUPgM2Bbq/AOaLxwik1OnIb4ECX5D01XMPmD7p7GMbyFf/VU@N3mG8OdFNRezaz//0e10ogNfF0@cXpJlbOx6Bb0Q2pDdLy46KL@S2v2QJzGCiyDxhA3F9CaXA4yAZr6wd@1GjPqZ9vj6vQ@EuVoULwok3qOzvyJlFuS4qk664eu5PhLB4tz9oxVblEckRPNEcIubtG9Ff9Gat@MSgUDS@S7BYzb4sbkrbKhdxzvcgc8yWUgKV@hV0rjqd9Ga0F3pX5sS64wDvl8pVHuNvP1eOd4WMDfMdTmQ0g@/Ib/ARyYi8JdlWhcH@kE9S@KHlfETn/sxa2dHlXg/6gfbzLTDo9JuiMQbDh5mRxztisWo9aNLK8@/h1BXr/hbIan5r7XgLELKqkNvPET4iDgLUEJQdnGbxbbFJfsFYhe8ssCfT//lShAmSZhmUTELweNggttDrYbnNhM54/HZ8NClI/Hh8f2xr7ocgEDRJEsUv1VxofeQRr/gC3S3nm4p41c/euPaADqAjCma0whsgJKbNZnEKxUJu7wkuNigCisvG9Y7YbshZjb6@NYC3iTOWBU2RjTEp7tXLWxrx5dDHBg3O8JHbJiq@veZvFzoN2Fj71q79lVoTTBxEe0OOvkJJWeNXOEK4JRh@7S3eCdoMf2@aCX1tKlr3/Q3Xci9VX6GCfAqRDFnYE70rfElccTqG3PZzcbiXKlNQ9vof01eapvdF1aADfnbV4ccxcOj0WwNq9UL5bZk2ZEUzoGeB9/d4AT0Iw7Du@6V5m20yr/rIsMa2e3@0vUSRRo5OkvsbhcsrPU2JxHoMD7c3JWCiS6jp7efXari1huK4L2qotdGjqZz9fFO1D@H/S8JBhlJ0HDPdcr5jS@1TZ/ZY29sZhK4BToTsz1yOjZGYfsbq9r1VALrQn/GL1fNv0Hq8xd1V6zFeEJMZbDqMEI@Bw9QtM/pvklro/dS6X6ejXqGNfikTW4U7VETQ2OT@qkjpAMv9zBgcy369xpKUiTgR92qQcmcg4rqSd3TH1xPF2tk4tIdAGGAeDoCsoZZ2h/CrqMb2HN/eVTi8IkMl/6I1s1fVjMHOHmMfugKOCjpeR@ypk/FO4W7xrjpRq@9zrj9e1Wytu0MkhvxcjRT7ss20Y4obIvm9ZbZnRxp0e7UR2BDqV5S/jZSMKVn3HcTEZ4N5IOP4m/4u3mN6PbkC9ivYI1Cq8tDw4SDe1ymewFv9dQIcj0OPTBXNBd7f4vY@RdrRNOXnlA7o066MZhoYn7iK6kul9Mr2sefZ6M3IhIGjHB3prTEJq62xO4/APewov1nQFciSSRqHrynlV4OG77RaW0OIX@pDQotNBn4MXVi536K3ipWb88f80XcJXg2MMSvHe8ji/uDX2EfjldFLhpBx2NkaaN5MDBy80D/jBXBK7voMoS@ORPL6jsXPdwcTY/V4E2iu4W9PsJ8hY6xvxBvLUOFVvO8Mam@ZRKamigZj8npPxL6KIvJgjVq@bynZ1dDtXuYWRnxPzH1RsjbDDrgCg8x2bTn3D0AcW5OiAkT7ghqxuoGaOhQXxuq531heCFCek9G72PZVcgFHN79Yq/3M3uHqL9h8al/rq32xr5OasX57q26ARJrWitL3MgH093ljiEtOiELa9PH6xjZ3FU1Rvoa7qBAt9ahp@wdes7jWswtRfxbeBd@BAPvxxTE6aLcJk0gD/lbd6YsTaJ4MzdTGoo@8vQWq4AiPdd8/llwoOw26JYt615puw6E93pQ7ikjPZCBhYGxPEOwfPeooGo@rmt6x4IEzq@fXjEcJmv6lJqHHa@Z4TB6PY2VikBsZwvVJ@8cmj@kcIfRrZEE2rYlOS2LFntYR@vKXCq8j8qYqDxm79tuv@6V8VxeTjMu0L4PefkUGVukLP8pAYju8ho/C/novF@114u8aI@mJri@@rBt2pyjXw6nWJAA63hqMseed9gSTZh9n81ez1u/MRNjTVG8KFDGk0Wj2iSxYJtybQ0M7Kw9sFijBoPkFLgmaMPyiLfHmYKU9q4msEuStuVfwfzmi8T4ZeVu9Qc/QlZ/0DPeX4BdoZ2XkkbUinVc2a27ei2nNtVXJGuX1KjbDay@uBj9Zt5fSGuv16gcFVdBFsqZttcaJPsCVdhPMu6npfprAuVy8x@N2U1YkHFLqqQC2giIrhnEVobUY2aAV2TAJrCzRd3f04ef5MXvMPdMJ2nHsoB8eLKxkPVt2PiZLfatW1LtD/iFx6PT5nIfOe/WYZp0EVFSgh78XlN@Bk2TysOjcZJ1WeWsVA7pXOT2xVkcafbICGfREF/RNA0xUInOabq3xsxaS1nEe6j/@VddemA02iUGPZAN6dD0VNxNoI7GvzT5a6dqpJ8djHhd2I45ZH5UZpu5LJ2ljhorJWo@tzehGrh6zV3faWx7gpYI1aIsKq1DROsalHaZVaBY1XU20xMJOeB1rlSlBUyYjFVqCrtk3/HRNJqs2JvpmLh5cCKaaOjaHXS9doLsizgCQxTjEAlQ0bUiWxSEl//GvrDWtZEkOiBC6V8mTNe1bKeLKG44sJBUEbQJUr5AsRV2zQVzIZLBCJti5AqEWLX83LlQhi21BEn2rpaaYjLXcNJ2s0b4s7cQ9GbiA7USWXIfJ6nnzjn1I/EiPGPE//R7j/mzzzfELXzRiOLz0CuTkGeVqOzgMwZtQJ@04nDvsbOHqf7LYfS1U9rYgF7pJca2Wjo7IxgEid@KMLB0lyzlUNLJwRT7UawNsENNNUFuVJnHomliWvK9m0mHcuALGMQ8ua6sBWYiDyyAxyuGc/oHuo6z4BJoLs/BmMUTBlbejRGo1ixvcnmtnMmJnQiadpgF/IJgg2Tl8TJyeEZcudjVcCX/33f08wPru59HsA2OsmHN/P/8FG7gB7mlgZBx@y2AFypYynw/9Z@wPPxj8gnY4np0n1toDqOWHnyuFSrZWT9YbNeDms5XZg5ymj/iNpkBZIOt7@ppCthgAW3RZNL6sPdYaZP0G4C4XfcjTp7ihye2mtpexEFCb1Q6f49ByrkHA2t6O/YXo@@Ib4lb4awBbM0kybWtRukIEyZYZp7GtQb0r2cJyweoONtGaI7gQZI8qJDxy0Angkg@49JU8ol/n0irBj8QDivHLjHofxz4UwKsNxGsAZNI6LcyvFW5lbm/mn/8/yPEY2rW/bY4JjndzjBDv5RgAN9FIjFyyUGxUs7uRQJw2@8mgR6Pj1kKJ1C1rZ4olXZq9CWKlmUhnwLAXO691q0FPZYN0FlDeJGwZoL9NqiOZezZQu1hLI@mkYoAm73ZBNXUWJmo2UOl@suTIWnfkU2nHATDLv25ovbSDQlgj8XoxPGiumQBa7Hsr8iGBI5gNas/unXuR@ekf/pm1Y@feBPcf2O45m4K3P7LfJHD/g1UIx8HbP1q/BeDtl9bbdwyy8vX2BCs3ayYiA5uFCm2Q/gyyaMTPt3KPbRu2nbIKFrU8Al5PCesQ3MrWhjMbPK67JnAeigvYjkoa9TJJT9QfXLi4/Jhh0BTBESg/Wd0izq3eDFlr/jTBvVbQlDCRcCTEgTkv@qYrhGS9aA@XU1gI3e5jkEpqKo8T33cE@vT0lHYYAq@IiciJxXLmkP8u6Ph@TeghwFKW1XJHQxyIsokBYWd2NNch7@HcGBUrp5Nz0g8nYJBYJQhtmos4AMSN3upqQSU0mprNKhAPVZybRPEvVtYYmEIqWc8nWjvuVoh8gMjCjTuCXkr5ZtEErifbknv/djE4WghWQ7Bjxz4hu/uOvjfv1Qd7ZxgNAvObPSKngvsP92wXW0tP8vU@JdfLXUaYG/pTTdVwIU0OqKVdASYQZLiIe6tOOWxUQC/WoB8AJdQZqIOCKA@0sZFMZwsX5Urt1T4bAul8CeaknWennnuf33v3sHY4X0j9iqmpHFO7SuVWrNymajMWjRCbAemXZO5L7SWlb6TeslarvE6bBLxKiGO/FjHpU/lyZM7mNfZNKLMFmLZm01@l6nJ/fr57OD27Vw9eJf/Dvj2IB/4jFC5w3RtkB6KT3qNzCqs1OHXcbG74V@s6A47NDtv12lfrfeP99k6Z9db1zXaZ1WofiqxzXi9zpvxvrAOCvPsZKymyV8QibEUv6JoVqRySuklQoF7NJ2xTQ9t5eb3L3l7Ou2ZS2erIkq2AvAp9GF0WLGiDKGiru0v2rUGHp2Bu@kjQ78J@NOkKLki3B1TFuifflclIKK@vluKuQ2riSPbVV/Sg4thsf7H3ffQhb4rcOeETd3N6vaz1vV0gfmOsyKYLt6TM/didhNy43JgB7hT3dMzdp/EHe/sMvdrl4iEbZSoT4FdFG9ObLnxGXLmq0IujMxNADmIg0heTEcBJ5FEVsZUQ6ZLmg8jAR@eKiDvcGmLnwT/qhiF1f1@cd@UetDQutxdU0i84brPFhsc9IqoT9LDFqnNcdLHNmJ@1LWiLY/wd75fVrjh34Yr94wfkDvg7Z62p0@14JQNkb5K9Vaf7cpPSSlnwpl1rNxt8XiiEeHytCHbrTjzu7xsULjuGHgikWDP1IjihDXVJI35MuyZkl5dB@2ny6rp3qV7D1N207wzbsxmt0h4P6bvAgwT4aRJTIi5ZwcFMF26OdjEJKGf0NdQuPpbymL7j/P4HcJNE3PQhjj6kwdzAfrubAtMUohwTtNAAw98xUjSDXhpSZD0PSbIU2acBUHuDSUXu9UkFBF6QXNNn3242PWzVQIur8fixXRq76jBOg1ic7tEYgHaPmlvZpsBfe@EocA2VGECloVMqg0L5dCmqKtRXF8jMCGonzU9AyHS3d3XKh3ez6ZukcGCRmLdXogKhu5vBs87Pigb2zCFzQnrAJ8/Q7n9/jw2/ZDf9C@a/ZfzMyWfXoZJYMGCMuc9ch/0E5wkeeTyH6pHrUEVz5NtvseP8fAjWzqPf4XfMAch3qLhPQJ7BOkocqieH/KnrsJsIHJEY8OrxuD9DhB8Nxv/5kH9mDr8Fa8ILPrpVO12HBtmfxfr93DPQhzXkkPGCzHzGfUrkjA5M/lD2eJAG/@EjEvAjc1/zkHblvsaQPvqJbeQyvdFKjezaKuuSeHXmiMVA2/t4rdHDZFOBNdn4uALe3gq@J2yfffS73x1wEehufYwEXZrnY5g98TjD3InzgD745GCOHLrj833GN6VFn/NO4sP@p4fKsFK5cd@76DjtPEiXHVzI8R0dDxwx1AFzxP4QZZjvv/8e7FD67sx/5n9w3/mcD3cuqycVpc@i0SNvJHbk/eR83HTdorTbFQi4gVv3dJi@j/L8kScU@KSeQEgcryDNgRPvMfhxdDhMZ/H6z//7f/7Vf/5j8vcr8vv3siyPjW4XflqfHtJLuIYSjf/EvexuuXl0d6SlCwx8sPsSKJPfwMVVnM5w0Fn7DndBfvwAf@QfrvUr3j8QH9ubgLy@PtDUwZlwsDzgOO5gQf4e0c3Nty7f/N2L4bjA/Td4wk3kw6dvgLOih1zHx582LGQc0ZhD04hPH1II09oB3S1v9Y/nPryog9WBArxU5/GPrnfwr2riX3PYHPqaw6qAf6kh/l118K@4xL8NUbGElzr4MZHwvHvRe/z8/seVizr4/vT7xN/ion/eNacOoAd1cHb28Pzs8d35v/OcnNj/oHtO1m94WS4g9uHZ5zv97szjuSNE353Z1J/6Hs6srODd//jd6YPH5zm9Oz31P56dzc98D9@d3VEHn6mD@TN1EHBAdbo/og4S89OqhSizwrRLZNHCfVcpQkeh7g2c@g4CuWTaG6g1UgccvIU3rxgYxNdqNpkpNwC6Uswma9nzQjPbqIC/8fB49umTxw8l/wnIPHsAiua/8Jx5EqZp0rePR/6v4dvjHpf1Sh1kzuYNxncKRBepgypJyQcMePiBOrg7uHN5Pno@sgo7ZbkhN7zSyvNQOVL@BA77v1yeQ7A8ZweazvbZPteFykGzYoNdsIs5O9LKXBecIvyxI3DKrDRne6zKqhy3wfLu/6isXZU1QKVBNHPOmoiVleDZK5evAJkECQ/gT2ZZdg50ztkp/LMKR67vHlnIqZu9v6fuaMf3Iqg3P@f0s05/xOmUH8KR8dPn50Dk6Y6YQeH4wx1u53xw0F7n4/0dKC/nw8kBY9zfM5budwRCjhOy5fP5@fExk6wnHx8ZHECanx56Pnl8n@BKnHlO7cfHg@7Zycf7Y58lZZa8HTCnH@/Pgj50RzzA8QD4nTKen3ltUMLzwz3ldM1arRb@WrPpzHIRh@V331qH4q3FgJflQi@4EJTZF3/XMX8tYS7XXfjh87Pb7b53njjtzdMumuyednD384BEBxxokrvibmiRuSDafZEw7T47i4TBIxJz@1wsmuxWlHvHeDy@d/jJIIWfrOJLJJK6zi@wY@IKARJXPJxI3Dt4/fHecRd4wLhhXzxCa7ovHnQ73O7vuNNTSAOTCLjB2@GcOzTdSX9@3v5zfX4@dZHLjX9uN3q6QWDI88ztAgB3GN7mn130qevUhX7ghfE@P5@hk8B9Btedy/3gfn62/ODucp9aWM/cwDgaWv7/Sv/QUPz/5/@qQRtgWzwfoJmp0qGw29VZiO5QxBXzxO2/xAdgrMsRdAaB4w4n77y7@3QUPIqG7j4@HPmP8Oc6vT972NOcusG4gbq8qnoJ7gALljrwn1QdXMDhxKp4Ith7xRWtRwfjJ2iFnFAHEM0B1wHUFBoK8@x0Lb6bJsZ9hmVPk9Kk3Q@0@/kziLQVCGaoy57Jub@fs6hXaDd90kkcfj7gn08IfvrZsQK3awbB73KekKk@x2fHIa/fcQ@OZ8fh584z2utHnJuYheHQyclRyHJHY@DmjtzW6DXYdSdrN4SIBi@coAo6OUDJdQIT3ZCrREfsySrY6NtV0xMOhz8wAXjMfxHJBuZH9nV2tOeKBWKeI8@nuyPoumBRPBDfHz5QJziPZk3aOXwOq4LTsTgh4oA2jDgNqvZUPKx45qu/o8yR5eLwl/1gUNDV7NAqdOWiLN2FzjWv05okfbD8oc9Md0QRui2ioqwOF4CeldKdyV3xA3WAhiRYrYYI16jCixNRnE0mM3F9pWXjmB8M@DG5fvrN7//0m//hp7/45U9/8fs//cWvfvvrX/0@/P4Kfr@0nr/8V/Ew3n/763/0P//0538Bnv8efv8Ofv/2t7/@p79n/cj7f4Df/7nl9x/s3xac9aMA1x/99td//Je//fU/@FP4/XP796cvfz/9yb@x/v8v@w@df/HTn/wHvNkvv/9L6q//9W/w/4//9V//u9/g///yL/76X/@Tv/6jf0kcf2Y5/u9//q@s@3/5u7//X/67f/xf/u6v37j//rv3X3@F/6//K/h8PZ1fg@dr8vVzfX79N6Lnb8ONTSogUL/6w5/@6d8HOf0TdP89cMM/7fFZl8cG@AP0/OGQZcH4uv9hG/IHhgOziGa2PP@A/uEeV@5zG0jA/89@YFiw3FgLco1zG/IPf/vrf/yX4PvDJxr8bMi/v4pu65sdyDWd2HWx0voDAP7zLZg/@Ok3v/fTX/73P/3mz376zR9RHI3nin6gP1ABGp94Q0/iIK75ERUOglpbubmNOxgi7jDc95nBOE368dOOl4X7aB8wAfxIwj/staoxjaMVbfsS@7CKvxfDR/oTBEMTRFqhU7zjC/ikoF9kd48SZzE6QXnpWII@o1MImIB3Eo5O8g4NFp5VmqAyKwiazgA/sDWbz6HT9D39/cr/zAKlzyj6RwJto0lYiH6kwNOO/yNBm8A48zlFsOG/bfyhG3@rgNWNvFK2x9wCnr/yoCBDXhKditKNCtyqhfN8fetZzybTeSpCp8qlzItH2AYK08Vsrr5@jVqhq6jhNYp2tlh8@Wo/2trxceJHLhSl4AlvEzwDBlsYPD1sTg749EOP8xSE/Y59@ByKBkLhUDgQjETC0QAXisRDkXAsyHJshA0HAlw8FIrH4tFnOk5RZ599p6fUWS1bB0T1Ms0FWD91dkPP/XSlcu17ps6gQ88EqDM6wYWjJ4sEoLM8cIw0YTWwi88@w6AobHs/0OGo1@v3@@GGTy@5yNN/@N0KhHu7P3jg4Fgu7HBE2EDU4YAG1vfRQS9Euk@P6CB9MoZsQ6NMXeFsYZyzlnnJiBZcuhjHhS0QPlPJuqIOHmU3Gb/tCQ/0Qqcu9/ombc60NYBhGNDbWPdDVn2QdV@kRXd4Hn8/94IUxO3LfN/DtNIgfq9ClNfgVB5slxEeSIPLg00cM5MlmqX8WFaBQDwWjsWDgZg3Fo@FwlwkHPZyAS8XjUXjrBeYH@MisTCw1hsLxYMhkBUvSEU4HqUORLUrSwxzRB1wDgd5yqqA5xKc4gEPmr9/Rh10RQnXQNFzV9dNH3TXHpMY7QjG7lkaIjq4CIXrEY7mCeim4kqNIEdzDsrB0wJ9kMul2VzO4UjhCzQKbJp1OLr4Eo6xbDTlcIgkJA0iHYBIfXzLRljc5OWQ8SWdzOUQwwBfAjHE4XAMrRDrRVm9RAFMxZdgEBHQDsfTGh0LyDWLohiJZVovLJtKOxwTi7wY/AFc0noLEWKz@IIBGClnhaQhzOE4X0WCts7hqFpwdlL5VX6TSYejYL0kk4jigmQ@bGXqEl@S5IJIOryB9DocPXD0dDBMHY4OOFGGHQ4BXMKCB78RuHBThGryDsfCygfmxOGYE2heGDocjyt/SAfoyef5vtkVe9a10K2nAEEFCJLnk2yuc37e6fU6@iKZPa@SoIuLPD9YTPROr2NH7DzCpWEsCBqOFi8vEYMeH3llf9AlBKkvgh4XjyKh8JF/Asrsq4cJjR4vMOgCgvaNctoI4RoBcAev1AieKb5jBa0uEkSe807HcQJCS2H1oRcu92cyBOOiDXkpgtZxsd5JzO0Lf5zEHJGo4/gIno6PjiA45y6adUL/y@G8dzjcd/GHj45o2HHs/PjR5/yW@0g7onHHsSMaddDuE100J7pKB06eMZ1lgj3B5xOe4UbzXrzjiUvuzzZc5@QZNTB0/j4/uZaeBOdduj8iYS7oXoYc7mMg9OSZYU6x@mN1hSe90tpkXgvgYg4fqHh6DWDpiXU9p30@0OQ0/MAswvBxwsqzyxF3YWcVCIrH7x2ke2nNOLiczmjA6XQ7TwDJB3LKGm3RibQT@la5R0UPuY8HHKvMu@I@6HXTvjhQ/ooWfXhsmLyOc08kqWPaEYk70BtPj4u/akg@eX2c9/ioEz49@zuvrv/m7@y79vviRVkNXYSjDp6pLp5sEIrTJ9hZ/0w9f34@PVulekkvFrzHt3r9lqZ7nkPq0Ik8cAZ3h6SSiWSvmlz1wpNp6sAX1ELaweHhIXVwWj9zBB1l/@N6vO2MIUO29ziei@Of/vvH0w@ev9FgnM9/9mk1SA2kM5Qu4mLMLh7QbQ2KxcJYKD3aOPD8DS9IhEoATuoExzIcB1j7BEWb4AwCfW9l6PTHAzJoRlc@SxOVzMYfX@Hcq4s/rpHjZu4eQG5@LMnK51jQd0Zmr1Cun4lgCGUyx0AdqJrtBD5Cf9wU5yZUg3DYgVIHRTauxb@Lfhf77qpRbpRzn9jj2HGMMP3@3pYVL@fknKQYHz9BaydXs9QB/YMW5n5UL04OjsfOYMgZXJfcfeLAYhMXdR@cBaJ@g18cPNhr0F0h8Hyw5iQD3EFr95rtvEzJ4Dx1ELv6Hjsmq/Oh5QBxMQxNHz6fPsP/2fPd6enzKa7mggf@W7fnZyuc/CNpqxfy2Fw7cBuYTfjfTJD8jwcPP/pOrf9TvKXLFhMckbDDffB94gyK1/ju8bvHA1AzcdoRIIXiYazRjzGez4/XkUr@ROMI/77beBxB9KP1m3h6ZNDhM@itgB/DMPfu6wBYNPF4JBY5oH4HDHtnRQ2ErqeYJVHUjclo3xxzUpeveJx/V9fzzOC4mizxGMpPq0PAV6YPjbYPLqJA42fbz7aHtrzI2fm7fguDwRW/6Av2M56yTj7kQEuoZ104PGiSlZv0EW6Qwo0Nbuoz9Q3gmggmWSwMtxOK@gZXreKrawXnpb81TDd2wFg39c03dqthmH7DfETkGMn29HEn1DOF7OG7XYMmh3DiiLa1G4LHNaDa2NpGrCxoK5JBWj/LiiMbGTDdLYKPaMmiAnJzRJMUCeWYOSv5byywzkRCUnKFYhbiQEdOIstI7NgOvYNH1JLsfZDcduI0C16IBcEJpwg4AgI68HQR3O4RbrkQXATSQ3MYLpHlKAAFRq2XUOKlJTviHb4@QHREL4GuMgCxlbrLygF99Ggna@dh1RhjJoCFmDvS2pFGW@8JXrv08Hituwc3/Xm1sNuFodCTDmxWntu4oDCsz0uQiMKoax@3mdiwmWDjHrxQtCfWAmHXGs722TDqmToyvaMTq6jGJ9SlS3B/xuUKJz@Ovv1W@G58N3o4cY8SJj49nhE0vUOXbIEcmYlRAsRjfCc/nJh3Ho/8kBi5L134jqfasgAsWcw23HbeIOdqAmjBJU2G27u8U30/qg/e3J3qAZIn3qPbxNLLJ1jvHH4y2C2K9ynB2fmANM3E0qOe8Kfww5UTO4uvwf7w8Cc7Xhhl6FISyzv@IQH8UCCix5ODzACdxp3i8Ty4IXEFAl9HPFG@/Zb3KGfzE8XncyPUd8GPuTsTHA@eBL4fu/jT@cfl3QTiH7vgmYBkFDcQD/FsXj@vaQf6ToDHVpluSLdonCN5cyBvlEgc3X48uj1KfPiwvJv7Rg9ei/3H7EYakPg5En@ytbjddXTrpl@whAz0uxy/kI9/4Qfl6PDKHg8w2TveimlReHQLIWOPZ0X1M@pLcuj9alUOSpi9INs6v5Mc3EcW2ZGjVA1yWq/Zxa0pEDdpCLJsg1t7isYy9KR53CTnJUfZ8gQCw@yvcGDg/fzjR2qVtL0GGFJG5dIRaR575OQMdh1nHcgXXaz9gF/Sr/vU8ErnrvuhtcJtloY@bzCyVV2JaiIVztCFOwRBNfCZfT6xNJa18huUDdEeAEO0B8L5UIsgk2w9YUMm7EAorVUBQSzUE5K1lxXPfTRQP6GFvK75oEIsMqAy7yFD9g4SRDeBPMngouVTkh44oKpQ30AmkAbMg/xAn4Eio7/9lrZfTxPQjY9iW4BgCDfwcAj0ilJI/CsoBRxI5QBkFPUhSQRo@wZDcGfDTkKhv11C9sYkF0TwDLzW/iQ/2Z/kmqiGtS0P@ea2yMCy@OabgScRsgmCf9L1gPgQ9vy7A7u5P6bT5atKo56tXiVrcIeeU2z7tOrVFyFenQM/xvPdO7JKVucLfJUT2xcCTbvAmDXxZD784EuXvmgU6UCglPHiOTrA@gNrzA4a1OM1JtEgZ5Qafk3vMTN5KDO7n5fCb3OQjQDkY1a@1bHWSA5pnJXNZsHNXkEDR8OgMbcP/9g5QXokGoZ9vL1v9ckgsvuabJsc4e4/qIX2cfhkjeVqmRhZlIgTY16y1FWXezL5DkzfQrATnxx7bFrRSf2g8Bj7Lm/yKNFUPMayxzTrRQe3cgRWjuDKEVo5witHZOWIrhyxlSNuO7gVZs7CDN3cYDCycUY3ztjGGV87Q@zGucEQCmycwY0ztHGGN85NaqF1apEYwUsfrLhJqq6oYxgXiq3CcLMvdGnQMwxouJeeISA08AoSoodeeUJ6sV3PaJy1EyowZQQKBCKbd9A@K9iEy6LKa9HhtVK23mxPaKsoq/NGBDar66CVsnP8bgcInfuYxs1PFAVqlxYUkQdjQDTBSknkQP5F97G1KVhfHG82QCGGBLd@h@h4KDbE4cgnaCzx2RMc2BdsYQvsxWbtqqbXjNnaPWYTaVF5vNPSWhhDO37bWD@ggkWOvgERsCCwDHa3m63SrOuTvUkG309yB@HeJF8RZeEN74uFvHER5IlVVNL@E2yJVXqWnSKS0gYzwP7gGJGBFwWKu8MTn7ljx29//af/K/3bX//xX9A//flf/D//9n9C97/B2/8GNgsdWAP88o/x9s/w9k/w9ud4@5OtSAQ@eOz46U9/A6//47@kf/r9P7aC/vFfOryhNSIIQa9NzF/9Pbz9fbz9Hw5veA34qz@0ADGKw/tM7ZhWLoD65b@naUgNsayR/elf0bTDAwaGy5a8O6uOP2ztJbUQrNlwR1wPL8OtO36uAXjMuj0OwGu/cZs3DxaAewu5zuMXtDZ1D8wZa2cCammBF/q4X9D20gy0fwQ0YTTD3wN5m3XB6LEHMZyQ@79LH9NOD8K4ce1mF/s4RIfb@bfz7diEIqzHwQB1eKC9jYp8zGJNCXRvKZBv0hNYGH7stpAeKWfJiM3fEn6hb9WAOFaSRc72p@y0VrGh00Pb3zkiH3tYdXVRaLEZsjaVk28cUPaGNm4rwR1186LYIJWXPtBl3Gwz3Y5KPMTRGIoEoq35jYzFF8IF70t0m5Kzq022nHtRYfDqgIk53NZI64QStMPxBVjktA3vRosruAtv0WsD3LHHwYedTav7gB03NzcOasuPRRnSuy6CYStTlspYB3G7QYGtoMBWENBs4SS6JhwIvKCBNByoF3c3aFvRtlTUbrSNcGHNWZUDkgF9QWuY0yspE6OfeI2aaORdZfca@RZK7iFh15N7leicM9rhfhUBcO7GSbwsy/2o2Vcwrwtqf0zk9o7PTmm9jWknzlalINyjXnJpXXJcfF/J7Sb4DmruwfOVCQXYv2VCvq9MKBL@ckIvixXj7qB/m79fVjsrNbHW8BtkVsU/2GmgsGn8UxC9jTpCinXidLmhy5O0uzydmUa79nzQCvyZ1cF5O1@x0reO08NOTEkzRWt44NNYgy6Hhlbw1mcw933/1v7qZE/VdNHY3owuW9v1VCcehyBoPRVaNS8e4Cfbn2jD@Xnr4JvddmXdstlWaNr6siaithiFlufjo6zK5uMjGJ@K5N4wEF/9Au6hclL4SU5wbcV3rU3b8til4UGkpvvLOIm9a0Wry8LQVR7bgU5IJElDh04QFeh80X38WI@hWSzBLFqf7wGLtGO6yIFBfW2k9URVw5MgMPYL9IUNbiSIH48JLV6a99LCFkV2J9oleHm3HfXyZ0elLwP4ualV/MAugh1meGn9JY@Rs/qe5B7fTM6Ktkqv9vPprW3TW3ufXknWDfMlzcQTR3vw@fOSDro2GABwQ0bwy2R47cNfXpGzQ8raGz8UZ0X4ahK7oiFA84eUJgE0aYP7JZAP7/rNgLc14c23@P9@Aa6iZ7@2@IgxW1uAvhmR7zqRLppBjr5SBdEF4AU36p7Xya1FO/OVadkdHdLD89IOorhU3IoHFXM8FlX8cJJ1rRB/QeZx4dAruSeriRJW4B6a9KmXHgbeLqLMY1dU@IXYddmQ3i28qxxXRb5L9NXXZRwVHVF6mvV1QBfr5XZMMbJlmgAdvyEyvHfqdr8tVhaIvJYeMhlHKCy8zT8ycPdSNeMgaMKaA9F00KAH5FQlcpbVeDFeWMcsKNZXiW09arU/VkmW8PSJLzIE@GB9IYzzbpJ1v6c@q651lr6iRVjD@nezjDupVxhxL/PrMvx5LPpyTskowzpSYlXKO9bJWyUuv1fiW1KxkknLKvk6kfyS0H21zG2JmoVso8LSP68JeYU5zSuKILi2MVo@75aYpr7SCeiHJaapb7Qqj3sU6jom0XQmfkglYdkXbkoGZwGeU3g24YkIoQ/6aAnUKm9o166GvEjIiB9vWS22z52AtugWF93b84hbUNTKjQO5z@s0hTfTFF6lKeykua4Bu0luAVHCTpJ2KWDxvFcEiiiZb2hnDMKeOzzeU9twqRqv49zrZ6fsPJa9tHPqPAaF7BSdx1kXKGVn13mcIQ7DeVwjjqHz@BIcm7rl/MF5vKoWCKDDK3F8Qn9bheO74DxOu9zPFPkW/Spdv/N4XaYA89F6JRx5toZXO/asv7YeVRXx049oVHpplBgDHhpm6@7BS34s/BNQ@6hCCPyQoANHBBg7IDuNxlaLYaUDzYaffOvata/5OF4NTdnjG5sxFAj3JLYGVVBKJkQfOQ@cu8rIIgxDyeAjPIFA1JvH@ymiuVc9sy@RY6cu40c3gdm76RPu@Yk90HWR8DsA3h7EUTbxV@W1i8IqwK@jEyO/RecrclbJEYpwMYB7D1nI1O@d72QKy/rFsXdW6W@X0OsxAixE3wrEKiWCdkungw2HtilJbKyNd4WEhOJsn7wdBy@7UqL0vohGtIJdM98IJt52zlAxbFd@93vZ2YqHpO2oIAy8Yx@sWrZuF4guxqCNrtuyVK3KByRs6ZwuOYdGRLHN2E4CZ6kbL2kr3mqGVnGtJInm2lWTENmPu1EnvGmlvpmXwT2qP6/7uooJJjjQiAi2Yq5TsfSr9jPsd82y31cG9YoJLxLYZ1jvb0pfm9fvtrIvKFc2yb4uQAz00hn3XuNoncKG5dA72LLM35O1VyY@fl/PMvKtRNfYX1j7K7at@wRf4NvLvoWFC60EfbrrOcSB2WHgbUa9tkiUqX9ltPgxJRuPlfE1pZusvU@rlfF9RYwh2EbD42cXsL5bwNuFh/hIBvQXLLdqOX48ncxTrOs2@dz2ZubCmnXQcJXY@hDHLU9Q92T92nqJFniUH6uZcqnYhkY3Go26X09FYK2FuJt2nHp3mmDdbQl48Rwu62vZGq6k0c0P96rj9ZIy4gHGAE/mbSzxs@u429ZlW/r8Rd2FeBbsFkdtXMNNNeB3tBKaOjw22bLNV@vbDq4j3kayMm@B317SW8NZI5QOnNB5fCTN1@MjLs55fLRbMSya9TTS7w7szzsGNus1qIPd1UzE4jJeHXaDAwCTkfV5a3sAzj7GxlqHcoBf4jZXsdexJqoprxY74PiQ/TVtay7fFeRwdKIgrX0IHbgowxUIYRc2EMbN/VYshMaBT7K00k7ng2Xo4GnOxlhTyXmc5IwzYrbj2dLGauiVkD1RZzxZBmKlQs4k2KLIWpC1mhezvuGtknOKIS7uHiNDyCveeGmx5yczPoE4dDmG8tg6pnG99MNwk0iEYLJGC3jcUcQRkFQD2d0zmnwlQ6n0c3KvB4LE2B8ssRa41HmI6tMkX3p1/NAB3eQVubs6CNdeE0YOobbHgYGdrp3zoww6EAFrKu4Fzm5@wFhcJkPjGVEsWaRFoOAXhUfUcsa8W3E/uBbu3Se3utyI74PrEUvW2jYq6/hxkimvbvHZ3k26NTRtT1oSPbA1c7k6Co2yj65LkHlKP65RG7scB47VAXHotJZN8IqwOlnJhWd6HVPfqETx4AowWrDW1oCBq6LRRqbX3OslqSr9CzoYIB9chvSIlUqSBRzWzN4OdgiDqEistbrPVjCOX3Qdv8DJROqbA9SFlqxh/JUoo5scibuRZfqDjc6aUMGqbFWB1Ut46yUIXY1v9iT8weXwABaPw@3YwQTw9uzHN5bmfR0VlKL7d0y9G2nltGQyWR9xevU82Uv2k9U2vKfYoqc1CGUZJptXuslMobM416L1qRRg6@3rVCfoqUS787GcH6Xz4ywlh9ojz21wHs@HluF0MJ0U2BvpvCiFoukb6cYQk4oYZ6aD4XVXrI47nG7Il6WrUnXJ5BrXzd71QLpttQZRtUaNq7ep3vVcvI611GmzES8Y12IzXTKHpYE54RblaCvSmKlGqllP9S8WhdlwXohobTmcvhajTWmcnwmL8FjIN6jbab0fqeUXwzg36i6SaaPbjno8TDud6sXyQvdWuqilL7s9PdwJD2txPjgdXUjjRf8yrz4VB@naVPCMB7lCZEqplcJ0JoZaw46SV2@rzWYnk6rMhpxxO@4OQq2ridmJ6ZFgcJIU@4NQuDAx9VgxlbyMmplkoZlTbprm7aIZq1Bm3qxHGxdCXPFMy6YQnGQajME25xfyZW0WyQfqWl69UAqDyvB8cl5RxpNhJiSX66OQ3rvJdbRAIH9dm@bbRUoPXbTaseogEMsIc4G5DGvaKFiPl4r61XySeiqLrbRQS4mdCJsK32S5wVV5IZSnxWq1VRm3GqOocckptzl2QJVvhFoyNcwVRzGuXloUYueF2iSdLsynnYDU05KTbit4dROZFUtioXXNBPP8xLzyyOmywgwuLoxFs3FZuCkZt1Ctry7kkLSYp5opXXrKpI2rapEp6cN@LTRQu@NmVE5rwkWlEDILw2R@1rqNF1JDUap0htqw3lJaE1PODJgctUgPrxsdcZaTlzM@Gyo2r5lBtiqY0WQvWGMGktQZKmVj2TsvLnu1SafXjZfP2Yz4dNlNNcPV7Ji7yhmhkrqg2vWUJC@r1xI3rMTzhdtONilfqeF0RRxXzvPTeSDQlqXKLLzk5jeDXEieCyG2WE7dXHmuLwJVT9GTSlW0YLlHBTK581YvfOnRcuKSKUr8UzTt0SeT0Dwzmci6WGyoij4KK2wsV/f0o4beil9dzTpG4aaabgnKMnZ7NRxGbqvUzbRgaHogdpFLxpnKkNXP@UGpcBuV1VxoljpXsvFCa9mImdniRInli73MRVXP1EfCTTzbqy0Ww17sQqwUh0lKjGWq1UGn1@zM2zWjsmCvQsKg48meZ0tPPajHzVoucNFIRXqTarB5mVGnlXrOs9RuWsVxujTkspXYJFKPBkfUdH4RS9ZMVR5nzq/ikeuJXMwmM71GmtNE8eZJuOSGfK2@YGNGVL/O3VyPDY9Z72ihTj8VXFxftZnmrWGE8zJ1O29FCsmhLlx25@aFEa2rAa18zXLXUqmhhKct@ald0QbJEXPZuFkyndkyN6@YglkbauFuNDw8nxtP@vJSv6Ri7QGvNEpprTgQIpdteRllwpxab6elK6F9EWCTjV7@Sszlp71lQxwFBvmnSV7gBaOSbHfOlch0PvZIwdi0SNVLrZte9OmJ7YildlxODhvVSsEM1Hlm0q4Vw0/FtmHkhEZBToVkdZJJtc@Ho/Ttgq8b8@WkHuko0qKiB9gsNS@1r5rCQOsZOeNWGCxvcrfq1SQQuSkPpKjZHXIjmSs2JTZaGlc9GU9FOe/0FpHmRJwKYBmOrwtjLpUcDMpUmRtFp6lF3DDVc@Oy1ElfJOVkshgLXI8D0fwwfZ6fd@Vmo1nKd3ktdNtJByPlTo8NdFOlbK8SGvWilVI0VExT9c7iusp1MzGZ6/NKenCxCI3jxUAqwjRn1fz1oN5XS0o62ZpLqaBQ12bRFi@pDXEZiTJXrGfQj1@oSTZUiVANM2M2irlZ0KNeFq4ClcVCuOnwkyAvPbUNj9Be9pflpshrSr/4VOXqzUkxLQ8GzUhKqLPlVI2dLI0ZPy5WqHimonKZ4nyam/VrLdYYZ/LjWGde6qYrFbEz7gbHUqecnEvstNW6vb5ulNXRzfUoX412yssuPwg3TakaKc9N6glMnua02Mh15hnJkAbV6ZN6Pp/cNJlQ43xUbHSnnkH8tj0NyjdltlhKNSV@UrjuRc1GaT6@ulAkhRkFyj2GmjUqy6UpJrVsaXbVnkvN5TIpp4wnbn7J8MXzQubG9MSzuWSmXK/xulIunxczSX40u5oVb6IecVm76obl4dMtVVFVJaDf1pRoig0agUY4s0wLg3N2cp4a1S/qcW7MNfLNq6tLrq8IIyHaLmcirSuhlUxeXC4uJL5ZqYwrl406VfaoN7e3daZcV4pxqVio1rVwYapftVpRfqYlr3m2EBp1ZsV5anY1mbRG8QtP2xT5oLYURa46U4qMmAfZiVHiZFpJlyrGIvC0HDz1phntphlPjs8jyfRC6k7F6ZJNZqYexsjNZ92IPI4F6u35udQWrnq9y2qqHxxPx/VIOkxdxKUrtdlJ96/iC/EyX2zmJqZY63ZCssdgx4P6dbJhNISFfC5E@tOG0Vag8knjcD2VjhvKbSZ2qcseNiakKKF1xVeYYj98U7roarP0/Kq5yECXI8ZJFTasLdTmJDZU85dG6rL1dBmL9Rqd/BASnvRv@4Lc8KS6HfFaUkrU7c1lc5itTJrM4PrmKlpp5D2xZVA/fxK0/jkfX9SXZZYVpXhvWpjMg@OiEDuPXZYF5WJeqjYksRepBa6Vc3VJZdRon01K3Gw6UxnPIpyKZXtSqlFS9UxDyEdFrcIzzLx1a5ZbN7HLwDl7zdZGMzZgXM0YVmqr8qJdarcDXSo1NS7HrRo3zXryZrJdG1SFc4UptaqFpbYoZgNGI1lKS5eT2WJcXMh68FYonqeViiBzYJaEI7263hguU9MO1ZLmxXQqFr0N5EGCDEOJz9ohXhSMcW8@YIpXk7wyH0yGTd0zmjNVz217Ho73m32DEYrFeqkwy@ph7cIYqFQkIgTyLX0cNapPo0UhbWb6zYYSSsebvU4532au6tJl/Dpdu42K4QpTeBLjrVqEFYrhlsBwVW00NaFFEnpDqrhgu7qgiDofnZSfwtnJxNNdTCemZ3wbPb@MtXrDNDcVeE8w2dGe@HnzQmHlUlTsGeXWbHqTa4GFqDanDZXK3TbGwUs5L9XyzfLVkKskq0uTScVbwk2o19Y5SZWm1aAZviiIvaggZbK3w0EmX3gqsG3piZ1xin59HczlOSoqeVKm1lWY5vX4Wl0GeDHZLseuZt1letQvSWK@EMjo7WqkW7vklSw0o/JTkR03c@fF225H6TOSppZrVZalbiOBbOum@sRNu9eVZV2b5/XeRbKiBG@kgqpVbppc5lpnStFU7jo9qN6mF7FIRVc6Yr0Xq6sjz3lQE/ikWoxQUXEqppotpiHKQS46X3b4ochwt63hMJZnlhFjySRVYzaI9ZbxzvmIa92WtPP6Ysicj@a3ldQNNxE9HFcRxtS1uayEz89bnsvFeaPQUxoFSWD40WJg5FMT8WLWuY4kPbExW/dku83@vFjpjVtZJtrpxLhaMNgKmU/dysK4LlHNTDEfjGYW5lzKDieleSw/TkZqi3njOhQa3g7m5VgtUg3Puak2zKbGuV6Y0W6MqDqv53u5lJiVriTjatkRRlRkOSkVcrGsJyzy7Ur7lpWyzFOtq5j9nlS/vAnWIowQzpcrs9vbTJIZRaVBtqCcQ5s446/mi9qgPexcl42gTGnltqcQWUaWtdvrUlettC6u@p1ZLxqt6PnmID5ZtsdVueoZLxuFjnaeqYyUzPIGBC5SjYcHDSXbaMk3mSpbpsxIKzkDG5xLFeVFjymE2UtJZS/mo/P4zagVGbaHzfS02p4PB5FaNKxNxGXUbD2FJ2Ij2r4Y1Rih0571PYFzSqstFzfZ65BeLM3GRbOiiZdsLFC8HTZG2UnDM0pf5jpmusWOO4FWcTbxpMNgFcSumvFAqXM5SBWG59dG/joQp@o5eTGJDc4j554KNCaTgVGONZWAMmVajNKcTcXhiOVLGb6pzzuNXLFb6gZizNgjR2fmZeTpol255c1xSGUoYxHpznhPPgsWREZuh2uepjlmR9AXYW@mwUu1FwwY6k2tJphpLTpsBONiKKc3Va051wbNgHx9Hh3OBPlyQKXEZTekNKqtbmm@nHXjw1CXr00bydyN2gqm1XF/buhcJH4ZaPJPlZEeLJvjSrEhpNTrEc9LM89cSWWu9NqU6vZKyW4r9zSRps1QORlKLm66bGhyOx1w6vIm2w4MKp1kX5pVW6FldRZMdc85tTqSxyM9wLD1ppodxuaNvHhJXSyz4qIfu05VmqHG5SA@DCq9Ya3CLoZlWRJub40JV2j3itdctxBupq7jw7xkJMVoIy5dDJh5qVO@jaS7YoilPP3CiAmki0LwInvjMS8EJfwkL7mSuYxL6qLUkDu13jQ5LnYHjUkplWdSXGB6Pi@PgvkqE5zwqVEsc6m3dYUSs@HkvFG@ihj926TZDGmVwDQ2vq3IvZtAt9LnhREbiYEOvup2bheNZDU1K7ZL@ZqRVHtL0aPPLtXzQi6XUqm81Co9GU@8Jk2SoUa52L5@uk7qvXq4YxoFbv4kMouFWr5IC8KinSwYw1LzoqYWouyom7qKXve7RbWhVeTgJSXEo8ObKKPWhIsJK4YqyVDuqXkuPBWmkao2VE2hnr3lzFIVlF0h3CiP27PRMt1npXkwlL0xyr3u@BZq62BJBSb5artblQbqfFa9MJuXwVGNGzZnyjCi8mNPKBsvl3muF8ROWPhGU0eactkzb2ql6aXOMP1lZCKOz8VLmSoGxr1koRq5CPDn5@1MvMGNnopiIHYVmiRngXL1yqOGxXGm0BspbHpYHYjXMnQZWpHK4IKtleRG73aSvokvatSy3ZHi6kVrpl2mh7PMcDqoN@ZB6F7Vm0XDqFVvzG5hGuhcRJVOud@tZ3LpayHN80a0rKaz5eF40uyMZvlQmBrkgjeDq@iF3IsMowVx0b6cjOOVi2Uh3c@HPG31Ima2eVN5KiuDp1LHNDtPUblZu75gWqmooLJPi6h5028xBpWPjbLnITG6LPS5aEMdTSeTbrmqaoVF5foK2BwNBOvnHSY5bl1XzGY3Lwo3@QZY@heaWKjdXIxr5zf57qSrUkoQxDfN6JfnRSN3kxnecrNCddGROc@wfDkrh6NhKd7xTMOjUn@SCYdb0dFFaZrLjPXI/Aq0fq@yqBTFaumK4kZX7ezQcyFxXEy/WjanoWpSvIl0rmbSLBTOJOdqPxZrsPPri3PhOtYZF2ajxgXXu2Zmt/GhMeIbfDUpaFKZSj2Ng4vM3Myy4exlJH9zLQ4is252EigkZ7VWIWLGS1KrFXqaVWdDsZTjpPp8OgtUcuVrUw2F583r2@EllEKYEnrz62xUvAqJXVZe3qb1nNZRG3ySZS6YwKzRvPZoPfWpJHqGlUAuOI5k2XmFh57xbWpy0Y10GgOldZ7Kx/tUNyRkPXUjUriNPN08Xcn6zcATHYHKiUnV6fUVmCQds1EPza@leJtbNtOxFt/JLbnsJZMM5fOTeCEQuCjGi23KqIVHIC1Ps8DNRUYJXFea9dDEkyll5t1@7bZRTc@uYrdtblRp1aYX2BkLMuxMKg@qjUUpN2/IYiQ7rGalFOUpXM@McnwsVTPNrM5UulIuNBjmz3Pn4uRSmMyzqoftFRqL6dNkJMYurhRe1NVc1ewnhWA7NgzOhcI4@XTZpBZ5PnvBpWPNmD6UhYtBqWEMjGlrLMnJ0FN47jGrg4p8Gc5U6zfqoNEvlXQhfRWIGmJmWBtFbhuDeWcqZrsXlGTGp4IyPy9FTDW1yMk3javri26NXQiV2EUpp8/ZDpN7qrFTk2nEapV6r1PS5eIAGk5Pu6FpMQVUitnXril@3C@ws2byshvrGelzNla8mJcbcsnDXmerg0zAmOoepj8qBzJLLXsRlGbRXvX6csTq6Wm377msRJnbQUqblaiw2Q22eGMYr0pcu91kxtnq0jCuYo2O5/JaYcRq4Daayi@5eic47k767Vh7dD59arevnjrNWh6K88YjRmpXT1Tv@jJvRKW4wHUbqXQxqU3H7IU@qkqhUVFrNwJtydOeZwqzp8AlmxsUOlyp1F8uU8KF3lJjmVHnKs0vBo1Ykwpmy2z3NiiOLxqZp3auPxkI6eJcCN5oecNzEyrNJ@d6LBrhQvEpbwSbo1HTE0sqsica7C/6gVR2GskwXb3aorJlT7qlaVALqrcRvsQYoW5JMY1GtF7LxqvpXDpfvMzeSMV4rcDf3Hja14V0NlmPXFz2h6HLNmekmNRVf1ALUINiethlTDM2kWtyzsie65l5/3Z4PZp0ZtFp0Wgv1Ut@IvdGnMSPh62iGo0kr5tP4TIbzF4x2dulogai4Xmc6gpS94JRqsObVkzO5pm20ocOdAbkf3hzNdEFSTf68Rbk/GqpRtONcq@p55V@BShUOpOxII3i8rAvBm@pKlOL5aIt5VISyu3qKNruyDf1i2BUmsyh/9rOLC@lDAOl3mjX@hP2JpIF0zUUeiq0@qPraalpVMOZZr1YCVHNp2pG4grZYrF5a3a5Upnt5aZmIxrLZzlhlBqWsotUJ1WY5YRGK@8ZeAL1rjDNNZNKttnljfnilo2zelIaUJFB5ColZThzFm5Keih90S8HeaWgzcsXsfGoWrkIpC6y15I21NnUdXJ1RZqL@EgOL3pSMnneLLTTPSp5nc4MAk3JEKqqZ1YgYKmcwv/uZx8VIuq6SsCoqSZ38WtZhmgfc3HyzsET5OQJ3N6@c@4ELvbZPkhAsvdXW58P9joauEP42EqEzG368UsqOLV48nJu0cetjhMgDzzHgz4iX0@RdiZCHTpGXpPxQVbfI4DMeJIZFJwHI9uTf2Ecww9o8K5QApvIjjoX4Y37i7QRjuA5H3jUKPtwsjXl@f8Wd61bbSRJ@jf1FImwjWR0xXZPNwK6BQhbsxgYJOz2wTQupBJUW6pSqyRAY/Nj98e@wD7APtw8yGx8EZlZVboAM7PnzPQZU8pLZGRkZGRkZGZEtpLEBgjSkLlBl@iZzzyHV4UXVJGPgOtH@7l5x/rlaqo@IRcNAvY0kikUM1xVe8UApDQIGU2kW98MDjtkMQdrD8SGc0uVH8s//MT@PVSQH@X7Zz@d51@2tzLKG/lu0I/Gw9vO16vw@qaremrw@@Vde/LXP5R681rBo9H6C3FDWvlhq8Q@oP/EHjV/YrfRz4wXUPbID09f7LkRTkdXlbJurqrLKscfefyzkanOcKl62TdcKE4@@mc/nG8FW@Vq/yw4rwZra7nR2tZorbKWRcKLSq46GOubiGejc361X3qp3pun9Yicgru/YVcdh0H7OlyN1F3da6fenLBHMzOB@u4gOZ9uvPYoHCZTuuAnt5@aiLNJOCV2p2r6oSk3mgw8HN1ZrwS9kPgX/yyNf3hdnc1HD5eW4EKjqu9OJDvwzRmML3t@e8NZYnriCBzP6Tc2tFOYtgLfLi1xmi@Jgovyoyyyqya3HQ4murIvRS5MXzYTILezOFvN5Z9S0pS6JJ68QJy7IRWTIkLeVHFFoPloNCdY4fvAC@w5KPz45KrwcqKWTZ7x@IPy4Bv2u3MxUj576aE/m0oXZR8YKqc9TnDqmY9Hb3yVYHtVspZ@H/cHfP5cFHw1RRDE92Lg@kNbsxiNL/G6V1VADN8gjRHAxz08wt24Iy85NGYscPGNH1@hP4B3zJGYCOG2i1juJBvx@ADwOiHXWZIo0Vk1CuVipaCh63I3cnqoiXDw0L46WN1QfA@uSkl8JFpN5P5Ouejrguw@Zffd0fWC7GvAHkeLsoeUjdjRC7J9ypY3kfPzQ8qXk/4FBUa45UnsejEKL0au38uKQw@4ArkXgZ1Va2uGsJYFlAyMjEe6vtKuUdSyjI4wW4q9aH4yW0kBsHRWTx78jrmFc@HAPit8kWhTaKK@qUcb05cjicQX3BKJXbSfe5mCrxII0PwjUapm803jMtq2oyn@KdKyc4XRJmK9Ut@/P4SZZsQ0/1XODffJCOEebqKHQq0YjoS2jcdVKv1VV5pfR7uOSUo3c0ci7oeZlOuxCJG5Fc/rrh90qA0CvJxMxpWnnPo5TjmLztWGlR4xHWVaPE7H9RnuwY0onpF5dRl/tp9OVRd8TzVdWpEvY2EBP2FudYackS1dSJfeptKWmlN81k7xjJ6l/2hnn9abFcKPJzXTpiqCtk2q4bZGcA56roxrUiYIsGerG5KOQLx@Gpi/AJj407sgAKNNwgErmxHjZk30g6K8SSU5X15/necr5lLkPiaTEVZPodP/w@QC4fSSPUZswrRIUnNIM1Pc9hv02p6eclPdE0k/v3Nn8qh59edV4Khm@Ym57mdaJTdUWVnHTVV1/7gc@uco8y0evpS@E2UXywoz6IYTn8KC9wsI/SiTpbuwfq5SFAcKLBkeWZLYCeH8RSm@Wn9hUsy1S5nbCzUwYFVN5wNnAWgySFFO1sprnWs7Fp3a@@LFyCg3@VgLQ0hg4QpS2atOUpxjO7fPi3cy1bqOYookc/CSHRrm0GDmd41uS2qwqVdsX2CYhcigJ83pqzDsZI3CpBUGhmA8dFChvLizsmqVqJdx89ScVnrVlfbyYdbdKqUs6yReVygByqfmTSDx8oqnTRXTJqHf@BFHrOZ8rEbUlHl9gMuKIn3UxnQ6SlsVaGluJSPx4ZOMPVdqOc8rcUo8ZHbdABdDMRyytd7MIN0OBMps00Y79m/JY3A/x8ogPjy1d8tvya2LX/WL0IntoJtbkLmqxWZzM4NmLMPf/31luTSOhqVLPyh5wQ0p1ZcTZ0V5gYRO3FDjUbfwIy4K107eftDShO9l8yVEYhMaKbRWDLzbLMqQ5gwvopmcIz7p@NJixYFfYr433vNuOqT1i8eWQRjd8b8T2iyUi@PBKOQc3RD7rlPf/e@xP9UyvyLSOwaNzibDictk8b5AUidyV7JQEQWpAp/LuQSIM9RkgZv5nMlg/ICovk96du5ERc9tXwMJ8N532U7RcDEn3zuRGXr4WgMp8HiFPnviZWLAd0fRBGsn0YR/U/fxu4IPSeErruB7vU9x@EIwcnphOACT4yoo6m8SAYTwS83WXv3kpKhjL8mNddxyl3vMeCLIDus4XoO9xovb6nAXKIOyhM4CtrS3FQNn@cs0QrOaTJgKtyCn0Ar@CKUHhQr/mumGLZ@T4kwSfu6kf0WgZVl79RiQHgXaxdWyiWoFU80UTpBi6VFquO02HEG89/ohYbzr9XqEtNBiKSYHPkER0/6abT86Q5vnFnnJL8zkF1L5RckXpOJSxfb1MC60kSyUWfkWl7tXmbhYfqatLUWdbhyyd6liOEzgXX2obFSkTZofF962QylcaTM2UxmFRM5vc0ZfcpZTdSyD2/wzydf8va5H3mKZKvtLun38dfQAeeyDQT9ZnOLSYuD3fhbzo81hCavgVkmqY7yZ7WRSaoOIFicFEhPExDxtt7diKGsVI3F4zmS2N3/JFLVJ6ufsNBo5fiEwM7HmzJEElbjNNSbcHa8k1A5nLydAMEwwmjIzd9tUnujKkwRYlFo2zTrGU2h6glPXpqf4Fq51f8c/ZrKnkTPlVuZnLgnmd9J5eWmRJhAL3eXMfDKlpcloOPYkUXfqgVUkbnsyDXG@kDgMsQNtX0NS2DY9eQ/SDcdBZ9nKiaSgMJJihu42R1M6LlAx7LtoCJF57/y99NJ56/ZJK@x5d6oGndplT/1O6rHNyItGEc0Bjzo4VNF4MOj52q@buuXnHNLPyvobPEaIISaUhqLTwANRKZ/Hl34cQ5WK6giQb/HOMM6IxlcIWA9LMGKvk2jt@gRyVHRqwYQ9E7MbtHV58uKpMfy4QgD3aNuXQEJGTmYPWx6gpRUd87BIutqV@R2MSAWijofs8xCuVjcc5y9jv/11961aL5f/VCm/qiRIZkzV5eKr16qRUJFMxnq5Ui6/qbx2nN1wMJGnjdl2DrBeFwAwrw6w0H8g3vRuEBvdqdGKwQUjUv0jb3jjdYqOc@J12AZ8OWaKgJXHIFdg/LwihXQr@Lsndbcf5RVtu64hXvAX67P4rm2zY428gzdEA2/Y90fy0ii88TsgoHk31Q17vfCWDdF4siT0QKW@NyKivMypNErsl1bjwroLu4slaiDmAzvwuwxv2I@0JgPpqT7c7/MDIAdOFAEh2VjQmcKE2mv3XL8PdpqDALwsxRQwCFDXOuO29yAODiPxD@KgdMc6YXsMz7yuGZkSSb@Q5wpNd2/ok/SNCcyjwtUSuNMAt941mqp5tN/6WDupK/o@Pjn60Nir76mdT6r1rq52j44/cZwx9e7ogKRLU9UO9yj1sHXS2DltHVFCptakmhnOcGqHn1T91@OTerOpjk5U4/3xQYOgEfiT2mGrUW/mVeNw9@CUFuu3eUUQ1OFRSx003jdaVKx1lOdWTTUnrqeO9tX7@snuO/pZ22kcNFqfuMX9RusQje1TazV1XDtpNXZPD2on6vj05PioWVfomLPXaO4e1Brv63tFap/aVPUP9cOWar6rHRxMdfTo42H9BMinerlTJyxrOwd1bon7udc4qe@20KH4a5eIRwge5FXzuL7bwEf91zp1p3byKa@BNut/OaVClKn2au9rb6lzTvYRqtC47J6e1N8DaaJE83Sn2Wq0Tlt19fboaI9p3ayffGjs1ptV5RwcNZlgp816XiFeLDdNMIhalE/fO6fNBtOtcdiiNeP0uNU4OszRIH8kwhCWNaq6xwQ@OpTeEpGOTj4BKujAA5BXH9/VKf0ENGVq1UCFJlFtt5UsRg0SEVvJbqrD@tuDxtv64W4d2UcA87HRrOdowBpNFCCYaPdjjRo95V5jnAgv@SRmdQzn5nk4VWNf1fY@NIC5Lk0c0GxobmGy7b7TNKe5XHLmHrk9eIA3e8qnTSEPO4nfPdqrk8YngWAycfopLTo/pg/vUnm00NhM@qlPQXmtuuh4l@OrCz/ohtia22pygt2PrvKIs5RDjN/PzgNB0vVBOVdYWbm4@FC7oH1u8@Iil39KzRQaj9XQXlgfKpXTfeyFboe3@SnbUpJQ2y@0r/e8OF5O2lpeWONDTpVKHU9Xw@NFADZmIh2UgIB1IBn5VaMbqESTfMScthVxxIxpY5E53gwj@if4Hv@QtSGRQMJZ7i2UStjDMhqIfKIs/tQIBwXRkUH4HoDf5SaLked9vcqWk81hy68NVDlTh8uOaBt4lc09Uv3Su5qqXpiuz8jirSkrK8YdvHHTDsYM@ZcmmdLjUhxyz7Ji2uM/OYMNN0RKYU6a4oes@vZJ9oVUh39RsRXmqtaVOIcDeV/7tfERm7ny@uvqVPo7my5zC6/OEduG1rszrnfOf96dSwGaYD62X0QSfyJHqqVSog5pZaxP2sLwVX@NQrd@h9ZULNXXHi/r8JAv7oKT9WkxHvp3SexJDL89qb3fOd3fJ8kJbF//@OZPP1Qd7XF/OPo1L38/oR0E42TqkhZ965OaxlmJWbJLes/@TLCcRHQfjB4KIgSlGTROdEmltZ4zRUeQ@BpiBkJ3I0QYCBBkI4MgAcOMwvt8b9kx/Dp3ZmoGyKa6mkNv@u4da/guqUrMA23xktmb8Kjd4R/AttPfTHHbIc1AmsW8/mA0Ic6lzQXLvcy@cTjAext@VowixYzh44Fr7iAJYSAz2QsD3uDzL83biVEkvRYDjfnKw841CYnlaSxMkBYOuURNHIeRmcGS6FPKr5rf6POTDg6ELIR6qI2aRMZ9W7NggveIzVlPDA35fHuLhujFC9vSpoIhNaeREvt/OnRMcjYwKnKhQU0BNjePLJ1tDhuhf1nNqW/CqfDqDThVzbH6N3HuvO5oKFXjEl3/NhFklMCKA8pw0q1twzFFPpkilpwpMv1L9GD4/0aazIG/SRtOgh5Ti@WwH4y9J1KSoQqtaPfKRPFvzY2xxDW1mJrJpE8xmPvkwFzbjulreHdysEQk0KMzMQmfJKRYdg4BwOSwayTnLxz48iS@dmnn9AvP3SU56R8G7f4gawJymaViBu55nnWuvLkihx85OcIvq0RzB4iv8gv7eWSZgQ0XSbHLiXoeZQTGWoVlDjpdeslGDzvLmTVBhoqZ4TE7lfXUMpP/Tt8wileZjsm9J1V0cbAvexyCmEIpgW9OQIwA4btPyQ5rslGb20B0br/h6YWt/Eqv4oh@SSKQ12XVYvcckdvlPTOWIu1LA0470CTgPO/omE2X3ugWy0VPoLMPkRiayj5nNyZoRNsirRphhG@uSFTnRfbWYs9mSvCrxf40@Bog@rInJi5TopiKAJV0wVpU710OBtV7Wr8zceNrIOt2uv1GwH5V2nJeCdMc79ypFez0n0cxRUjjvIV2SetQTCW3/RWJGcOj/m3Bv6M/3FZB99zENKI9A0esm6f03y/cEIBXpu7AqsznwBqRNmQh23pu1Bd8ydy1X5/wpe3MW9QpQo5ScGFWq0FAGXoTLmnOzjbGL@VWB5dPN0hzur0tXrrjvht03b7fm/Ct09/D66AUBeNoUBxMnEwmk7YGwhE4XKQQ7iNPffSDTngbqR2aDjAkNQ9Pm8dpw1/C8rUrli@l/kxtqB1u2ZkB34XPpCjsjmhovKqa6KDow9jcw3ZCbWlhs9YECXBMNWQGonb7VjN@e3iq3nqBNyR98JjvXKoDv@0FJD5ImeJbmNG1SBoU30frTd262ofuwpadqvJ8NupY256jG9DQ8mCtLE1FQniowyrCNj8hVk/YBIuzHY771TFGpetwoL0BwWgKZVNMnN1xL@8gduPHRusdNuOyMWfbDC1rxtYHW6KoTn0x1lJnhm4wmhBRnGnjDaH9mO2mqNgZEEF0FpOTN3V9RG/vwOzXi6iriGivpQCvIDRVPf8GweLYDPeUMeJ7ttpsFtOtqv0r5iV8nREdqdFz4tHLI2ZoMa/e/KRaHnhXHffcNu2wVHOM6q9ekR64E0YjFH1fU6q8XqlUCpVXMNGeNmtFngj4v4kg5jiN98dHJy0ipHaRbxjDrpkgPgftkttYRI4CQndR779AIJvyJDHXvzDxoIIbP76ZqpxYZDYyNPZtF@Ze6mGUVofZJAuTfDjkwGHwBkUslJqO1CqcHiBEHwtJtJSAnufQZTr4mCwtFk/25scVvgC3HvFVD@ehX7gyp5EA8O44jWoNeWfQ0W7vaUz6Xt9i74/M6u5KAWc65pklmNhSiTlW86vQkoh6uSScjoc7EhGiB/Sjm/aQZIt7QyyHKyzGJRbxDMumnO2Ne@n3fJoDhFf7OsSCI@LKDASbIJIR0RwecRtrBwsS4zInWgHNrk7Yt0UFK8exzuB0@iCatEO1ckXbbOy0ooHndThSwnggoQCQX6RZ3qOVQ9zEbcQxApyVMt@bHJKwQUgWkn3jHnzHwtffpYy5Y3pDXGXcC7ausa0XQNSj5ognKSK2ZefssPMK57w5HnaXGAJ1cyDEAkd/BGKQx6EUYUXjzQzBX8wuebij6vF4T/sBREUORhQN0hmAJae6XjrDgEff9edMAWHSLYvAlItBg4z4yZLvlA0s/QP9xb1TOE3LSh@pc5OcJea@jxCaYhsI1VWIf1G4aCgmZ4QenxHOOC68g0tegjddsjJbkkrZACKJkutzYBbmwnw1H2ZBw9SHlY3ghh22oRazhfRCvEGHJB9BiLj7b0MjetmtXC@UAybb@6teeIm4TSQpqDX8meTjgU0m8w4sRehkrjgRTMeb2jRd0qjrt01Gd1GbND@8bbVpLBbbnwMZKJ2xJXOJfZYpXrt4OvEn/tEzij8zqeBV0DqmolcBPUkl2Q2wGQ1Sp2Q2VDwzcRMnWV63nK7ST1WpTFXRyKWrXKaqrDuxp9Kp0UUNiH78TffM6CV8K4lHQG3ZASo7ffdOdjdldkDHZhqEjEx5xFs/1wyCgmdtZX3aofi5E7toTh3bSxvmJ1/B4xvfmWcZDnlVTsc7uDNX91gMcKlU/oTdgAdZ3aGcJgP/sO6fcwYZ3a9NrhIkJJXtsGQ4qW4P8VYrm2wlt6FWBq6cGqJUhIUt2fQZ0wCn9Bn676XK6gYKSWSlENzqalFIhGfXy2e0lZVhMXKw7MQrM/9KCDgaQUfkN18Zk2Ugm03NKyO5LUz5nJHdBArpAo5bcsT/Z0R6naRiRUmIhiYUPoQx1Uqed0fbMz5jZhC8/liLtU4Un8ZWemjkz@KWz82qke7FwtLTS8m8MolVxVLhocKG2JZOCwsvXm2YdLAhQN5J8QTpDmAk1qQzS/BqJCRjLcUfsbPTsO2LhEqTLSF0pW5@jgBOD7lBLj/VKyfhylz3cHoZcVIrZ4pJsolfCNOunksgOwGUc1K1QP9FA47rjsmJvbBcRcrpYV/EERaWGfeH2MIWNuP@EFtI4cSwP8wWJpahJS3Xn@aL1EgICXApUe8Y2KaUlEEm4y5Z6m6qFCM0OU/6Mvd62TnYJqSqtnU6M6qSJZEOXZJug//cycCsaEejKXYk4p3Z0TiPe0trXPur17EemXXv7RZpO5NeEmQ0pwMRoNOmBR6j8xxCZtsKJLHFCKb3zH25u8ke7Vdlw8J7UETturpOv@5NgTWrSjk3q1Aa7/0x8ptzkS/MRlGIt1gbs/Hh7e0yjTUuPIXDDkpnnDknvs4jWK0lsEr3LjFCaRIvgFR4EqTCEyCVEpD0xH5F6yV/rgwRp857DMTnz7Mw@M9vtJHSMEjSdnwYsbEPvnUnj8FcJmVrhe/UuXKrzFaI9eTHYPw8DYPjgl7b0zideO3C6vZXbxhOR@VYSNk0r8zByGK1MotWHmix1Ob9ri5nVCXe2xa/Xl77diew8vhIix9jXRlXia/tIdBK2qu@BRbP/8oC@uUTw5qeD4J4ygxD2rLzD06HIgghFiZ5KmYrJARZeh@qM9KEeDh3WvjxbnXa@zECni6slnu0J7@IwSdhdKpQ10RipTjObOFi4WRWKyPf5m3PHm1/ZW77g3BAOk53LgJcvg87vhilpkR6rJpOba2ftJbNXc9m@5XU26Zikzx9kr@Y6fo6dR0P02lSB96tXv0fgqz7Ykbgn9DkzwyPLEDy@VwkcdDuauOWCsb9S2/oPGWqS40i/sgeaTHnOs7Kiqq1acusPePDKtbm8H2ebhJqMBghUuMBzmsiudyJyQ0bmScMPF22E94GXLqYQRNso@17bqBd5esF82qI8wtbNo/wnXjcxS34QZsIHXkJ8@cXiUnd8XQObiQ/QNbq/LEHV6NNjUU@bkmjJbpmdpLe00rqAgXHajVcamNaUTG8g8PQl6KZa32JFPPcfBPYU7SnhxQiYuJFTeoN7xToh3l0YzExxwNLSjs0TyDlPHXLWrmfoG5Nnqpu/RsoOT2gTuJbaw96gd14VKhNb/Kdv5dKNjBjf47rlg@t/f2Uw5PLidkV9L3hm3K5DCc4l27EpxYpbzg4JfbDUrp0CTbx0uD2z8MPlyVUxaEFIhNsmMNMLwp7JGqiYji8kmgUwIGKojSOJsAnOJoY03qTCPcAe06AVzm/R1JSPPB0FF/j9O3l9g8tZj4GCeJ5G@oLOoj@fVHdcSBG9FtXtgwairlvRrWhht5kzDU5Ig8SuvCoY6@kMTDeN@tXCzj42Nr@5izxGbg8F@Rw8blv8TPEzDuv1wvz6mM47HWWM/I6NF1hfz9ZoSxFcJVQJk/E4Yvzyrvxe4kQzigC3MKeV@yFVwwOJ@D62SK/ZRp6A5ykZbGOnXhX9btBNnP2W4YYk7q8hm6uqcw5nvdcZWiJyvAR@uNgJWAGof2k0n13kG0znaYL0xqo31LFX4TRq0peNeV2MOwpu9RlXObIporkxC@M0Ozx0iDqfHSLv4d@kKWuI9vBczl@@s3Dyz1ZUNwSN/P5rtIFDcsCQ@OEED1Pq3FfhdOpf/5/sG7DcoDHjWzjtU9iE/7Gkv0wxnjMLHUz6nZpeoklftu4GjPgWFQWKnxLAaTRAzv0/kCsguxqN1qVACu4atOcBO0UImfr53m1Oh51f1wlCP9SHx0zA/X0I3ri2sR/FGha7485jncsz9gMhwsUs3IHFS5QwXGet7f@uM3WajX1bLC2pmq1HfooFFRtp6b2kLCzo/bo9w5@v9haf/OmKjfn9nLfKHHHJN6rHYLBS9AabQT26CflbWFHha0UhvhZaetZvvrsYmtzuxqVzmo756XSFX397T//@2//9T@lmv7xv/ixwz/OfrOFisVi6Vn727MX91X8Pts7X312efZscL56VQWX/R8)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
158 [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf)</sup>

### Explanation

Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck(HDBF) is a brainfuck extension that extends the tape to having infinite dimensions instead of just 1. There are 2 new commands that are added to navigate these extra dimensions. `^` and `V` change which coordinate axis we are travelling along. `^` changes the axis to the next axis e.g. If we are travelling along the 1st-axis(x-axis) a `^` would switch us to travelling along the 2nd-axis(y-axis). `V` would switch to travelling along the previous axis.

The changes to incorporate HDBF mostly happened on the 8th line along with the other brainfuck derivatives. The line now looks like this

```
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[
```

There has been a HDBF only loop added between the boolfuck loop and the SMBF loop.

Before this loop is `}--<^>++`. This construct is a no-op in brainfuck, SMBF, boolfuck and brainbool. It is also a near no-op in bitchanger(It flips a bit irrelevant to its output). This construct is more interesting in HDBF. Assuming the coordinates are (0,0,0...) and we are travelling along the 1st axis at the beginning of the snippet (we aren't but it doesn't matter where exactly we are as the tape is all zeros at this point) the `--` sets (0,0,0...) to 254. The `<` then changes our coordinate to (-1,0,0...). The `^` then changes the axis we are travelling along to the next axis and we are still at (-1,0,0...). The `>` then moves us to (-1,1,0...) and the ++ sets this cell to 2. Since we have a non-zero cell value we are able to enter the loop.

```
[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._++._^<]
```

Inside the loop we start by perform a standard multiplication of 7 by 7 to give 49 in cell (-1,2,0...), we then perform increments and prints to output 158. After the last print we then change axis and move to (-1,2,-1,0...). This cell has a value of 0 so we exit the loop.

The next commands are `+-+<` which set (-1,2,-1,0...) to 1 and move the cursor to (-1,2,-2,0...). As this cell has a value of 0 we skip over the SMBF loop. After the SMBF loop is `^>` we change axis so that we do not move back onto (-1,2,-1,0...) which has a value of 1, instead we move onto (-1,2,-2,1,0...) which has a value of 0 allowing us to skip the brainfuck loop and the rest of the loops in the program.

Comment: I'm wondering why you censored Brainfuck in your title but not in your body.  I suppose it doesn't matter, as long as the language name is in the body it is still searchable, it just seems a little strange.

Comment: @WheatWizard being consistant with the other answers is why. Both Snoring Frog and stasoid had answers with censored titles but the name in the body before I answered with any of the \*fuck languages

Answer (score 9):

## 159. [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), 7460 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\  
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`============================================================                                                x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L  
#R+.----._>]|  
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 999; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈ +-------+ 
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/| 
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/| 
♈|       |
♈+-------+---  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<110
  
>{-<<mxf  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --9ss
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"5""6027""ing-?" ye h m 3 ;p se do{--}gibe
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rc@vKlhj2@cD5B/mCTekekuIDAN@URO3Np0iJIik@RT2ODggCJEgQoADwuY9OjZPUtWfGldjXY9d4xva9d@xUpir@4HKSKrvsqlTFX13@Eccfp1K5/@BmrQb4kijtfWbiqkAi0OhevXr16tWrVz/R4Y3@739/gBdd0ZRFT9FM2hQNk@7q8lTU/XRqQX/iZSMcCFIUQiX13mQkqqZxTB3QHE3LqiB34Z02taGoyktRB/8ATY91rafzI9rs8yYtGgI/Fg1am5jjiUlr0v5oQZrOjrSB7MOYI1ntAZgp6mNdNEl4iKYbqsKPOl3@RUj4RYJjHcINOiMqP4x@MGlBG414tWsAZISmM@VUtph8gSFK01eaboiIRxANQ0PPGE3Ps6LwAjQOoLwua8Vk6fxFEMfS50A6P1bEOc13DFPnBVPWVAzi6FqpUau8jBGgm/Vc7qVvkL70aSqdmwjDnSBSBhVd604E5I/ZFyEYeSrJimhQAuT9jB7bJelHB31A6yLftcAoSdNpjEKPhgot08J4THcUvu8XaEUG2Bwbo0UsAnoJ4UrfoOfjEW3II8BiaCNxmxaDVkWxSxtjUZAlWSAU0OLcFFUDcmz4aRlon8mKQndFBSJsyBK8gIyeGFteFhF@qqtRNFzC@EUm1m@HIsCo4ooR4hhKAhmhYcEBV1b8mOn8eAxEAjNrQLgpj0D@ZNNp0CJvyCjhEMUQ1S7h4Xgt@xrNq9u5pKcyT/NA70QnuA1RxwL1E7x0X9RFQMmvpc8102UTWIAsTtIVkdfpui6K7t16sJMkJKZhCiZmxE@K8PTUmS3nnFCUVgw/PzapAz1Yv76geNqfoA8fT@CXcDhOqGwpQ38@vEe3JfZQ3GPdxbvpxI@0wdzfi/Cbcx2mpz9TgJUCrig0o41NhveNgUCfCQQyPDrR5ZsG/GNlK2H69EVZbAmYBdWF0qALKt30kpwJE13Hqr1hKj@ETCua2gN@Qmb1iYr8UOkIC0UgaFAzvbQ4Ba6ByJMy0maEw/W@DIVmYJFsVSZLQRGGgooC2bM5ukrX0JQJgYOYhokCCFyBqIixINFNWuJlBaNAOKKyqNZFY6KYGGeidrHkQQGJXT@9IkPQugg00qaQHA9IiQfUp9FWLSREATAUhEayikE//f0/7/Z6gCcpCJretcW1SXc1gahSnhAL@olGgdVUXiFkAZwXU7eiQwJTXpG7vInJqws7CUIESXWmTZQurUGC@kyGqtXnp1AdJUkUTNESckv7eukRP7R0h2xJLmR8xHegYEkCJG2SbR/9KQ2lJIjUAZEZ32hiSjHaN87SToP5zvXx2PXxw70IxLn97qNDhumdgMD5j4gXvDnfk5xmckc7GiZvaHKXGi/MvqYGaJ9AO4SENhZVl3MHh9Pr1DtOtx91mst9IicEvySrXZfzFGTxDBJ2uk@EhHAnHz@cvIi@nSSgmSEarK6iS3A7KFA5pFJMmREvq/7xgm76bNdWmGY8Issx2L/ljYx56Te1PA5I64NyqaGAgB7yG4oojl2sn3OjmkC4vfnGgH05fYHDzvCx/OBxHjg921knGCCnOxnFylqXNVRbyriPDQwwRTXGoL51lF2BB@kxUIubYAJ46Q6Ra6L6QbMQnTgTnbpId0CRruSIVEmrymF8HypKG8OmCq3gdmu02N2q0KAMoE6bxiutrGgzSJjQhm0YqBAVE@d7UEQQ2cpQ0sqQlSLx2c3aUAXFgtg6Ih3zdWSoDFjtQLfbsr@VRwAPBiwYwGZVli0dNOIXgEWw2sRNxaFlCerUCNSEvqAFEXUPKCHRalgwkQmphwYYP2gGsb5AOLxb115VNVNnkr5bUNZL5t0ahZnfrlSocGhJnNEKr/YmfA/tLxWi8IIgjk1bYUFODBNU0st2h3j67EbUb/Spw08v0yaNid28bqWByt4qPbtJ5FHL2BaYTwGlSvO2DUl3ZR3Uk7J4mToATF8k7vgeQXYI@N7xBgkrSwCETJyLwsQE7QaCPOvLQh9kF6lTLf1oNUYvkwev7dRBw/ukddJIDHf2bYDyM2svJONNFD4s0dd4oJFFVGc7HqTwtz3ex8wboz2ItTWJ0CBs@foZ3g@y9wWcI03V9iAFRq7RIshuiFUOYJHV0BqEBmxlfpHKujYR10UEZQbaA2o@yF/fNMfGMbQXstmfdPwgKUxdXxTMsorCwpj6QjY1y91RtA6oZwPqJ7NKgREmHXn@IkPEb12GA4OagiEmGXQCWvCnCUidyykZoDiJfxqBt4IcRIETFNbdAYAEyA@MckkGUck5UCq1hSq4HH5SlfxQ6Rxe2oEV1@EGB8Za8yWtjVAL0S1iIKDFl9JBc0mgrWzdT1Q/v7fJW7cBxL5zOv0DTVZdn50fPnxwHjvPQMN/@PARXKfo@oguD7g@EpePuBDOjy4Sw0tcGHpHYqDfg/P5boV57n7AYptj67SUxy7@7vg4@ODl7zj7GcCnG1QdaDaA9uED8DjdiQQ63W7H2Qwy6u9Iu7lPo3auCbo8tplwwU95693mQpCwQR6NNR0N2RNsbN/nySihQ2sIxqvQd@nO@zv2/uH@833Xc//s9GJs9wmf6ECmID3XyN/TtQk0m@670LGPe3C774LQWHYSTtZ55HLFfAokxLvdv4i5PbzFbZdTBK3tur93AlNt/twJfZ3gm3sDbveaVUAHNtBgG7qc/s8xSL/jfnB7nBDX7fRCVyPhdAJnBGSCQTKNkkkYlAMBTNeKO1290RDUIy0YCtoUPt0yK@CVObI8u@SxNp2O6QJpWVVoL4EEaC676y6Oqqk@dUIMYWKlatsJkc4YQhA/bDxQMco7MIhYkudg6UPFXawsGmyA0ahJQ3dPU0R/i9gYDhokn8b66t9r1lSsdsEvGJtCBAMGnGOFF6Bm7qK7d9D3gBAElWH2h7hPXiF@afOQ7smX8ggtg8CryL@uTMzviWz0kb1gImGfQJeAq2h7Q@MuEq4VaAEa7R5wWpzLpmWMgyDUMEqeN1xuNP@SlvmEVhs2@UjUqutO2mNNgI6LCE0/hlq9QDqrTmVdU5HJ/iygBok9wTJ4gXwfe0GMkslCIPM2f/chB4698ua2eLuN9SVzBUOgGVVTtJ5GHwEAiqbfbws2VI56fyJSotDXaMc9NCGBM5rpilMGBdIBuroPtpAP7A1RJ63tOpo9eEOZ2gSa7a6oyCPZLJBRDEXFtmmjd1ehaSiADYKKLJqUbVBumisc0NioErVnwWfnqHEMSiRPulTOZB8ryXo@4WAmhs4ocgdy2BUfR2BZKKLhoOkDuipCbDvCcqhUNc1MkEqKYyevrwMEWsEXM4/FQqqarLatZEg8Qx5NFB4Ts@Br5N0isLA98CLp2mhtRRk2bw@DyE1xZwANuxZ2aAhDJ/bw2ZZ/FP1HOPTlF6ieINA@zXpde9qAMQTE4TC/MB5TPY8HIcnw2NrThowTlDhE5tc7K8/PHPuM/uvxsS1bdRvjvvC3I62RcwS5oU6M8VbmPnMB4j81JQmV7do7SLyHPkADVhbh8J5hQRs8grBdrSMq80jIJyqS35wv/WjAREKU9aB93bcg9sSl5st9ESgTrBHfXHoRwOuURWEdVEZRA/VQlA0yirotFNS6HbqnHKvGdKfNdGxCApvOLe2b7u@VO7YREfkEiRpqaMNtXI/QAw0jljWK0VB5HVMCTUpuO6CviHodYtWLUUcitz0Ax3ZHDyo5DjsiVy5w0Ar7mhq0a@KMgBGTlSADbskqz1TJA43XffTsmuE7xHREaQIqnwGbAt1fAPPFYwRS6nTkt0CBL0j66rkHTJ909rEN5Kv/qqdG7zDenOimInbt53/6gy4UwOvi6fML0sytHY/ANyIb0pulZUfFF3LbX7IEZjBRZJ6wgbi@hFLgcZCMV9aO/ahRH9M@X5/XoXAXq8IF4cQbVPZ35MyiXBeVSVdcPfcnQli82x@0YqvyiOQInmgOEfP2jegverNWfGJQKBrfJVisZl8WN6VtlYs453uQOWZLKYFK/Qo6V51OejPaC70rc2LdcYD3S@Uqj/G3nyvHu0LGhvkOJzKawXfkN/iIZETekmyrwmB/yCcp/NByPqJzf2at7Ohyrwf9QPv5Fhh0@k3RGIPhw8zI4x2xWLUeNGnl@fdw6op1fwtkNb@1drwFCFlVyO3nCB8RBwFqCMoOTrP4ttgkv2CswncW2JPp/3wpwgRJswxKJiF4PGwQW@j1sNxmQmc8fjs@mhQkfjy@P7Y190MQCJokieKXai60PvKIV3yB7pbzTUW86mdvXHtAB9ARBTNa4Q0QEtNmsziFYiG39wQXGxQBxWXjekdsN@SsRl/fGsDbxBnLgqbIxpgU9@rlLY34cuhjgwZn@MhtExXfXvO3C50GbKx9a9f@Sq0JJg6ivSFHX6GkrPErHCHcEgy/9hbvBG2GvzfNhL42Fa37/oZruZeqr1BBPoVIhizsid4VviSuOB1Dbvu5ONxLlSkoe/2P6StN0/uiatABP7vq8OMYOHT6rQG1eqH8tkwbsqIZ0LPA@3u8gB6EYVj3/dK8zTaZV31kWGPbvT/aXqJII0cnyf2NwuWVnqZEYj2Gh9ubEjDRJdT09vNrNdxaQ3HcFzXU2ujRVM5@vqnah/D/JeEgQyk6jpluOd@xpfapM3us7e0MQtcAJ0L2Zy7HxkhMP2N1@94qAF3oz/jF6vnXaD3e4u6q9RgviMkMNh1GiMfAYeqWGf3XSS30fmrdr9NRr9BGv5SJrcIdKiJobHJ/VaR0gOV@ZgyOZb9eY0nKRJyIezVIuTMQcV3JO7rj64li7Wwc2kMgDDAPB0DWUEu7Q/hVVGN7jm/vKhxekaGSf9Ga2atqxmBnj7EPXQFHBR2vI/bUyXincLd4V52o1fc51x@varbW3SESQ36uRop92WbaMcUNkfzeMtuzIw26vdoIbAj1K8rfRkrGlKz7DmLis8E8kHH8TX8X7zG9nlwB@xXsEShVeWj4cBDv6xRP4K3@OgGOx6FHpormAu9vcXufIu1omvJzSgf0aVdGMw2MT1xF9aVSemX72PNs9GZkwsBRjo701piE1dbYnUfgHnaU3yzoCmTJJI3D15Tyq0HDd1qtrSHEL/UhocUmAz@GLqzcb9FbxcrN@WP@6LsErwbGmJXjPWRxf/Br7KPxyuglQ8g47GwNNG8mBg5e6J/xAjgld32G0BdHInl9x@Lnu4OJsXq8CTTX8Lcn2M@QMdY34o1lqPAq3ncGtbdMIlNTRYMxeb0nYl9FEXmwRi3ft5Tsauh2L3MLI74n5r4oWZthB1yBQWa7tpz7ByCOrUlRAaJ9QY1Y3UBNHYoLY/XcbywvBCjPyehdbPsquYCjm1@s1X5m73D1F2w@ta/11b7Y10nNWL@9VTdAIk1rRel7mQD6@7wxxCUnRCFt@nh9Y5u7iqYoX8NdVIiWetS0/QOvWVzr2YWoPwvvgu9AgP344hgdtNuESaQBf6vu9MUJNE@GZmpj0Ufe3gJVcITHuu8fSy6UnQbdkkW9a0234dAeb8odRaRnMpAwMLYnCPaPHnUUjcdVTe9Y8MCZ1fNrxqMETf9Sk9DjNXM8Jo/HsTIxyI0M4fqk/WOTx3SOEPo1siCb1kSnJbFiT@sIfflLhdcReVOVh4xd@@3X/VK@q4tJxmXal0FvvyIDq/SFH2UgsR1ew0dhf72Xi/Y68XeNkfRE1xdf1g27U5Tr4VRrEgAdbw3G2PNOe4JJs4@z@atZ63dmIuxpqjcFihjSaDT7RBYsE@7NoaGdlQc2C5Rg0PwClwRNGH7RlnhzsNKe1URWCfLW3Cv4vxzReJ@MvK3eoGfoyk96hvtL8Au0szLyyFqRziubNTdfiJnsvS851nRclSxjXi90M7z2@mvwk3V7ta2xXtJ@UFAFXSTL3lbLoOgDXIw3QfaYmu6nCZzLxXs8bjdlRcJRp54KYCsosqgYFxpa65UNWpENk8DKEn13Rx9@nh@zx9wznaAdxw764cHCSpa8Zedjshq4akW9O@QfEodOn8956LxXj2nWSUBFxRD3g/I7cJJMHhadm6zTKm8tdED3Kqcn1gJKo08WKYMq6YJKaoAVS8RS061lgNZa0zpOVf3Hv@zaa7fBbDHokWxAp6@n4n4DbST2tdlHK1079eR4zOPab8Qx66O@w9R96SRtzFB3WUu2tRndyNVj9gJQe1cEvFSwkm1RYRUqGtC4@sO0Cs2ipquJlljYCa9jrTIlaMpkpEJj0TX7hp@uyWRhx0TfTNeDC8FUU8cWs@ulC3RXxEkCsl6HGImKpg3Jyjmk5D/@pbXslazaARFC9yp5sux9K0VcnMORtaaCoE2A6hWSpahrNogLmQyGygT7XyDUouXvxrUsZD0uSKJvtRoVk7FWpKaTNdqXpZ24bQPXuJ3IkuswWT1v3rEPiR/pESP@pz9g3J9tvjl@4YtGDIeXXoGcPKNcbQeHIXgT6qQdh3OHnS3cIEDWw6@Fyt455EI3Ka7V6tIR2VtA5E6ckdWlZMWHinYYLtqHqm@AmWK6CWqr0iQOXRPL2PfVTDqMe1vAfubBZe1GIGt1cKUkRjmc0z/QfZQVn0BzYRbeLIYouDh3lEitJnqD29PxTEbsTMi81DTgDwQTJDuHj4nTM@LSxa6Gi@XvvrufB1jf/TyafWCMFXPu7@e/YAM3wD0N7JDDbxmsQNlS5vOh/4z94QeDX9AOx7PzxFqeALX88HOlUMnW6sl6owbcfLYye5DT9BG/0RQoC2QJUF9TyC4EYIsui8aXtcdag6zfANzlog95@hT3PLnd1PZKFwJqs9rhcxxazjUIGOTbsb8QfV98Q9wKfw1gayZJpm0tSleIINky4zS2Nah3JVtYLljdwWxacwTXiuxRhYRHDjoBXPIBl76SR/TrXFol@JF4QDF@mVHv49iHAni1gXgNgExap4X5tcKtzO3N/PP/BzkeQ7v2N80xwfFujhHivRwD4CYaiZFLFoqNanY3EojTZssZdHp03H0okbplbV6xpEuz90msNBPpLxj2eui1bjXoqWyQ/gTKm4QtA3TJSXUk09MGahdr9SSdVAzQ5N0uqKbOwkTNBirdT1YlWUuTfCrtOABm@dcNrZd2UAhrJF6vlwfNNRNAi31vRT4kcASzQe3Z4HMvMj/9/T@3NvXcm@D@Q9s9Z1Pw9sf2mwTuv7cK4Th4@wfrtwC8/cp6@45BVr7ewWDlZs1EZGCzUKEN0uVBFo34@VbusW3DtlNWweiWR8DrKWEdglvZ2nBmg8d11wTOQ3EB21FJo14m6Yn6gwvXnx8zDJoiOEjlJwtgxLnV4SHL0Z8muB0LmhImEo6EOLD4Rd90hZAsKe3higsLodt9DFJJTeVx4vuOQJ@entIOQ@AVMRE5sVjOHPLfBR3frwk9BFjKslruaIgDUTYxIOzMjuY65D2cG6Ni5XRyTvrhBAwSqwShTXMRB4C40VtdrbmERlOzWQXioYpzkyj@xcoaA1NIJUv@RGtT3gqRDxBZuHHT0Esp36yrwCVnW3Lv3y4GRwvBagh27NgnZHff0ffmvfpgbx6jQWB@s0fkVHD/0Z4dZWvpSb7eyuR6uREJc0N/qqkarrXJAbW0K8AEggwXcW/VKYeNCujFGvQDoIQ6A3VQEOWBNjaS6WzholypvdqKQyCdL8GctPPs1HPv83vvHtYO5wupXzE1lWNqV6ncipXbVG2GqxFiM2b9ksx9qb2k9I3UW9aCltdpk4BXCXHs1yIm3S5fjkzrvMa@CWW2ANPWhPurVF3uz893D6dn9@rBq@R/2LdN8cB/hMIFrnuDbFJ00nt0TmG1TKeO@9EN/2rpZ8Cx2YS7Xh5rvW@8395Ms97dvtlRs1oQRJGl0OuV0JT/jaVCkHc/YyVFtpNYhK3oBV2zIpVDUjcJCtSrKYdtamg7L6834tsrftdMKlsdWbJbkFehD6PLggVtEAVtdXfJ1jbo8BTMTR8J@l3Y1SZdwQXp9oCqWHf2uzIZLOX11WrddUhNHMm@@ooeVBybHTL21pA@5E2ROyd84m5Or1e@vrdRxG@MFdl04a6VuR@7k5AblxszwJ3ito@5@zT@YO@woVcbYTxkL01lAvyqaGN604XPiCtXFXpxdGYCyEEMRPpiMgI4iTyqIrYSIl3SfBAZ@OhcEXGHu0fsPPhH3TCk7u@L867cg5bG5faCSvoFx2124fC4jUR1gh62WHWO6zK2GfOzdg5tcYy/4/2y2hXnLlzUf/yA3AF/56w1dbodr2SAbF@yd/N0X@5jWikL3rRr7WYP0AuFEI@vFcFu3YnH/X2DwpXJ0AOBFGumXgQntKEuacSPadeEbAQzaD9NXl33LtVrmLqb9p1hezajVdrjIX0XeJAAP01iSsQlKzje6cL90y4mAeWMvobaxcdSHtN3nN//AG6SiJs@xNGHNJgb2G93U2CaQpRjghYaYPg7Ropm0EtDiqznIUmWIls5AGpvMKnIvT6pgMALkmv67NvNvoitGmhxNR4/tktjVx3GaRCL0z0aA9DuUXMr2xT4a68tBa6hEgOoNHRKZVAony5FVYX66gKZGUHtpPkJCJnu9q4OAvFu9oWTFA4sEvP2YlUgdHe/eNb5WdHAnjlkTkgP@OQZ2v3v77Hhl@ymf8H8t4yfOfnsOlQSCwaMMfeZ67Cf4DzBI4/nUD1yHapojnz7LXacnw/B2nn0O/yOOQD5DhX3CcgzWEeJQ/XkkD91HXYTgSMSA149HvdniPCjwfg/H/LPzOG3YE14wUe3aqfr0CBbuFi/n3sG@rCGHDJekJnPuJWJHOOByR/KHg/S4D98RAJ@ZO5rHtKu3NcY0kc/sY1cpjdaqZFdW2VdEq@OJbEYaHsfrzV6mOw7sOYjH1fA27vF94Tts49@//sDLgLdrY@RoEvzfAyzJx5nmDtxHtAHnxzMkUN3fL7P@Ka06HPeSXzY//RQGVYqN@57Fx2nnQfpsoMLOb6j44Ejhjpgjtgfogzz/fffgx1K3535z/wP7juf8@HOZfWkovRZNHrkjcSOvJ@cj5uuW5R2uwIBN3Drng7T91GeP/KEAp/UEwiJ4xWkOXDiPQY/jg6H6Sxe//l//89/@p//hPz9Kfn9e1mWx0a3Cz@tTw/pJVxDicZ/4l52t9w8ujvS0gUGPth9CSKTXMXpDAedte9wl@THD/BH/uFav@L9A/GxvQnI6@sDdXAmHCwPOI47WJC/R3Rz863LN3/3YjgucE/jNvBg5MMnGtgqesh1fPxpwz/GEY05NI349CGJMK0d0N3yVud47sOLOlgdOMBLdR7/6HoH/6om/jWHzaGvOawK@Jca4t9VB/@KS/zbIiuW8CJRPyYSnncveo@f3/@4ciGO70@/T/wNLvpnXnPqADpRB2dnD8/PHt@d/zvPyYn9D@rnZP2Gl@UCeh@efb7T7848njtC992ZnYFT38OZlRty9z9@d/rg8XlO705P/Y9nZ/Mz38N3Z3eYy894mz/jPeCAinV/hM7E/LRqYcysUO5SW7QSuasUodNQ9wZOfQeBXDLtDdQaqQMO3sKbVwwM4ms1m8yUGwBdKWaTtex5oZltVMDfeHg8@/TJ4wdB@AT0nj3cAUm/8Jx5EqZp0rePR/6vYeDjHpf1Sh1kzuYNxncKRBcxe1WSlg9Y8fADvt8d3Lk8Hz0fWYWdstyQG15p5c1/uTyHAHnODjSd7bN9rgtVhWbFBrtgF3N2pJW5LjhF@GNH4JRZaR4qR8qf5myPVVmV43bQvf0/KmtXZQ0QahDNnLMm4mYlePbK5StAJkHyA/iTWZadA51zdgr/rMKR67tHFnLrZu/vqTva8b0I6s7POf2s0x9xOuWHcGT89Pk5EHm6I2ZROP5whztAHxy01/l4fwfKzPlwcsAY9/eM1RY4AiHHCdkl@vz8@JhJ1pOPjwwOKM1PDz2fPL5PcCXOPKf24@NB9@zk4/2xD0VuJXwHzOnH@7OgD90RD/A8AH6njOdnXhuU8PxwTzlds1arhb/WbDqzXMRh@d231qF4azHgZbnQCy4EZfbF33XMX0uZy3UXfvj87Ha7750nTnu/tYsmG64d3P08INEBB5rorrgbWmguiHZgJEy7z84iYfCIxNw@F4smvBXl3jEej@8dfjJo4ScL/xKJpK7zC@youEKAxBUPJxL3Dl5/vHfcBR4wbtgXj9Ca7osH3Q63@zvu9BTSwCQCbvB2OOcOTXfSn5@3/1yfn09d5HLjn9uNnm4QGPI8c7sAwB2Gt/lnF33qOnWhH3hhvM/PZ@gkcJ/BdedyP7ifny0/uLvcpxbWMzcwjgZL4L/SP7Qd///5v2rQBtgazwdodqp0KOx2dRaiOxRxxTxx@y/xARjrcgSdQeC4w8k77@4@HQWPoqG7jw9H/iP8uU7vzx72NLFuMHagLq@qXoI7wIJFfeU/qTq4gMOJ7oODE8HeYq5oPToYP0HL5ARbZoztgAtdlJOGUj07XcvxpuFxn6EQ0KRYafcD7X7@DLJtBYJ96rKneO7v5ywqGNpNn3QSh58P@OeTA0yBfnaswO0qQvC7nCdkDtDx2XHI63fcg@PZcfi584yG/BHnJvZiOHRychSy3NEYuLkjtzWsDQbfydoNIaLBCyeoi04OUISdwE33wT2V6Ig9wAe5HW/XUk84HP7ABOAx/0UkG5gf2dfZ0Z4rFoh5jjyf7o6gV4Ol8kB8f/hAneAUmzWf5/A5rLpOx@KEjAPaMOI0aN1T8bDima/@jjJHlovDX/aDQUEvtEOr0MuLsnQX@t28TmuS9MHyh@403RFF6NGIirI6mgA6XUp3JndFMNPQxgSD1hDhGlV4cSKKs8lkJq6vtGwc84MBPybXT7/55U@/@R9@@u2vfvrtL3/67Z/@7td/@kv4/SX8fmU9f/Wv4mG8/@7X/@B//umf/xY8/z38/h38/u3vfv1P/sD6kff/AL//c8vvP9i/LTjrRwGuP/7dr//kL37367/3Z/D7Z/bvz17@fvrH/8b6/7/sP3T@9qd//B/wZr/88ldQln/1r3@D/3/yr//q3/0G//@Xf/FX//of/dUf/0vi@HPL8X//s39l3f/L3/7lf/nv/uF/@du/fuP@y3fvv/4K/1//V/D5ejq/Bs/X5Ovn@vz6r0XP34Qbm1RABkDS/uinf/J3QVb/sfX2d@AN/mmPz7o8K5g/RN8fDlkWjLL7H7ZBf2A4MJRoZsvzD@kf7nH5P7eBhCT@6Q8MCxYdy/ywi3Qb9I9@9@t/@Bfg@8MnGvxWoH93hcBWPDuga1Lht87EHwL4P7czaMH94U@/@YOf/uK//@k3f/7Tb/4YQjgaDyn9QH@gAjQ@8YaexEFc8yMqHAQtt3JzG3cwRNxhuO8zknFC9eOnHS8L99E@YAL4kYR/2GtzYxpHK9r2JfZhFX8vho/0JwiGNok0S6d4xxfwSUH/ye5GJc5idILy0rEEfUanEDAB7yQcneQdWjA8@DRBZVYQNJ0BfmDzNp9D3@p77KFa/mcWKH1G0T8SaBtNwkL0IwWedvwfCdoExpnPKYIN/22zEN34WwWsbuSVsj3mFvD8lQcFGfKS6FDkbe34OPEjF4pS8CTvEzzXBfU@ngg2J4d2@qF/eAqihxHOPvtOT0dzCZ21bB0g6mWaC7B@@o59@ByKBkLhUDgQjETC0QAXisRDkXAsyHJshA0HAlw8FIrH4tFnOk6d3dBzP12pXPueARX0xpkA4qQTXDh6skhAXOJFneEAZ8JqAheffYaB09DUPWl@P@M8JHYhP/swc9/ARVPfUPQ34AWX75myjiABKmeYETLmTduj4oXyiT12igdVWeOnDi4cd7yQFTft88UNg7oX1a6VIBWlGxW4VQvn@frWs55NpvNUhE6VS5kXj7ANFKaL2Vx9/Rq1QldRw2sU7Wyx@PLVfqBt8IEOR71ev98PN3x6yUWe/sPvViDc293XA0fY4YiwgajDAa2/76ODXoh0nx7RQfpkDKUPFsNnn@@5J3dE6gpnO@OctUxNRtzg0sU4LswBuJlK1kV18LS@yfhtT3igFzp1udc3aXOmrQEMw5ite1GtVZdp3XVq0R2ex9/PvSABcfsy3/cwrTSI36sQ5TU4lQf7aoRH7uACaBOH/GSJZik/SmsgEI@FY/FgIOaNxWOhMBcJh71cwMtFY9E46@VYLsZFYmHgrDcWigdDUDe8UJXC8Sh1ALImSwxzRB1wDgd5yqqAJy@c4hEWmr9/Rh10RQmXcNFzV9dNH3TXHpMY7QjG7lkaIjq4CIXLKY7mCehV40KTIEdzDsrB0wJ9kMul2VzO4UjhC7RYbJp1OLr4Eo6xbDTlcIgkJA1VOACR@viWjbC4jc0h40s6mcshhgG@BGKIw@EYWiHWi7J6iQKYii/BICKgHY6nNToWkGsWRTESy7ReWDaVdjgmFnkx@AO4pPUWIsRm8QUDMFLOCklDmMNxvooEDbHDUbXg7KTyq/wmkw5HwXpJJhHFBcl82MrUJb4kyQWRdHgD4XU4euDo6WA8OxwdcKIIOxwCuIQFD34jcOG2D9XkHY6FlQ/MicMxJ9C8MHQ4Hlf@kA7Qk8/zfbMr9qxroVtPAYIKECTPJ9lc5/y80@t19EUye14lQRcXeX6wmOidXseO2HmES8NYEDQcLV5eIgY9PvLK/qBLCFJfBD0uHkVC4SP/BJTZVw8TGj1eYNAFBO0bqLURwjUC4A5eqRE8U3zHClpdJIg8552O4wSElsLqQy9c7s9kxMhFG/JSBKXjYr2TmNsX/jiJOSJRx/ERPB0fHUFwzl0064ReosN573C47@IPHx3RsOPY@fGjz/kt95F2ROOOY0c06qDdJ7poTnSVDpw8YzrLBHuCzyc8pY7mvXjHM6Xcn224zskzNhTQRf385Fp6Epx36f6IhLmgLxxyuI@B0JNnhjnF6o/VFZ7rdstuVgIxB6hT8F4BWHpiXc@hjQFtTsPP56MwfJyw8uxyxF3YrwaC4vF7B@kEWxMmLqczGnA63c4TQPKBnCNHW3Qi7YS@Ve4doGsg9/GAY5V5V9wX98RpXxwof0WLPjw2TF7HqTOS1DHtiECzCN54Pl78VWPyyevjvMdHnfDp2d96df03f2vftd8XL8pq6iMcdfBMdfHshlCcPomfUAefqefPz6dnq1Qv6cWC9/hWr9/SdM9zSB06kQfO4O4IWjKR7FWTq7GCZJo68AW1kHZweHhIHZzWzxxBR9n/uB4ePGPIKPM9DkHjgK3//vH0g@evNXbo8599Wg2wA@kMpYu4lrSLR5BbY3ixMBZKjzYOPH/NCxKhEoCTOsExF8cB1j5B0SY4B0LfWxk6/fGAjPHRlc/SRCWLCY6v0Pxx8cc1cqDO3QPIzY8lWfkcC/rOyOQbyvUzEQyhTGZJqANVs53AR21imuLchGoQDqPV5IYiG9fi30W/i3131Sg3yrlP7HHsOEaYfn9vy4qXc3JOUoyPn6C1k6tZ6oD@QQtzP6oXJwfHY2cw5AyuS@4@cWCxiYu6D84CUb/BLw4e7CX0rhB4PlhTqgHuoLV7zXZepmQ@gTqIXX2PfabVCdhygLgYhqYPn0@f4f/s@e709PkUF6PBA/@t2/OzFU7@kbTVC3lsrh24Dcwm/K8nSP7Hg4cffafW/yne0mWLCY5I2OE@@D5xBsVrfPf43eMBqJk47QiQQvEw1gjNGL9AgNeRSv5E4wj/vtt4HEH0o/WbeHpk0OEz6EKBH8Mw9@7rAFg08XgkFjmgfg8Me2dBEISuZ8glUdSNyWjfFHlSl694XD6grqfJwXE1WeJBm59Wx5yvTB8abR9cA4LGz7afbQ9teZGvA@z6LQwGFyyjL0WhSyafqqAl1LMuHMk0ycJT@gi3gOG@DDf1mfoGcE0Ek6x1htsJRX2Di27x1bWC89LfGqYbe4Wsm/rmG7vVMEy/YT4icoxke/q4E@qZQvbw3a5Bk2NGcQDe2szB4xJWbWxtlFYWtBXJIK2fZcWRfRiY7hbBR7RkUQG5OaJJioRyzJyV/DcWWGciISm5QjELcaDfI5FVMHZsh97BQ3hJ9j5IbjtxmgUvxILghFMEHAEBHXi6CG73CHeMCC4C6aE5DJfIahqAAqPWSyjx0pId8Q5fHyA6opdAVxmA2ErdZeWAPnq0k7XzsGqMMRPAQswdae1Io633BK9deniA2N2Dm/68WpfuwlDo3gc2C@dtXFAY1gc0SERh1LUPFE1s2EywcQ9eKNoTa32zaw1n@2wY9Uwdmd7RiVVU4xPq0iW4P@Nqi5MfR99@K3w3vhs9nLhHCROfHs8Imt6hS7ZAjszEKAHiMb6TH07MO49HfkiM3JcufMdze1kAlixmG247b5BzNQG04Iosw@1d3qm@H9UHb@5O9QDJE@/RbWLp5ROsdw4/GewWxfuU4Ox8QJpmYulRT/hT@OHCj52142B/ePiTHS@MMnQpieUd/5AAfigQ0ePJQWaATuNO8Xge3JC4AoGvI54o337Le5Sz@Yni87kR6rvgx9ydCY4HTwLfj1386fzj8m4C8Y9d8ExAMoobiId4Nq@f17QDfSfAY6tMN6RbNM6RvDmQN0okjm4/Ht0eJT58WN7NfaMHr8X@Y3YjDUj8HIk/2Vqb7zq6ddMvWEKmI1yOX8jHv/CDcnR4ZY8HmOwdb8W0KDy6hZCxx7Oi@hn1JTnWf7WoCCXMXk9unVBKjiYkawTJYbEGOY/Y7OLOGoibNARZtsGtLVFjGTrSPG4D9JLDenkCgWH2d0Yw8H7@8SO1Stpewgwpo3LpiDSPHXJyyryOcyPkmzXWjscv6dd9anilc9f90FrhNktDnzcY2aquRDWRCmfowh2CoBr4zD6fWBrLWrgOyoZoD4Ah2gPhfKhFkEm2nrAhE3YglNaqgCAW6gnJ2q2LJ1saqJ/QQl7XfFAhFhlQmfeQIXsHCaKbQJ5kcNHyKUkPHFBVqG8gE0gD5kF@oM9AkdHffkvbr6cJ6MZHsS1AMIQbeDgEekUpJP4VlAIOpHIAMor6kCQCtH2DIbgxYyeh0N8sIXtflQsieAZea3uVn2yvck1Uw9pViHxzW2RgWXzzzcCTCNkEwT/pekB8CHv@/YHd3B/T6fJVpVHPVq@SNbhDzym2fR736psXr066H@MJ9h1ZJZsLBL7Kie0LgaZdYMyaePYgftKmS180inQgUMp48aQgYP2BNYIJDerxGpNokFNYDb@m95iZPJSZ3Q9o4ddHyD4G8rku3@rgbiSHNM7KZq/jZqujgYNh0Jjbx5vsnJE9Eg3DPsDft/ooEtlfTnZ9jnDzItRC@8B/skR0tcqNrKnEyTsvWamryz2ZfOmmbyHYiU8Odjat6KR@UHhQf5c3eZRoKh5j2WOa9aKDWzkCK0dw5QitHOGVI7JyRFeO2MoRtx3cCjNnYYZubjAY2TijG2ds44yvnSF249xgCAU2zuDGGdo4wxvnJrXQOrVIjOClD1bcJFVX1DGMC8VWYbhXGbo06BkGNNxLzxAQGngFCdFDrzwhvdiuZzTO2gkVmDICBQKRzTtonxVswmVR5bXo8FopW2@2J7RVlNV5IwKb1XXQStk5fpkEhM59TOPeLYoCtUsLisiDMSCaYKUkciD/ovvY2tOsL443@7cQQ4Jbv0N0PPYb4nDkIzuW@OwJDuwLtrAF9mKzNoXTa8ZsbX6zibSoPN5paS2MoR2/bawfUMEiR9@ACFgQWAa7u@VWadb1yd4kg@8nuYNwb5KviLLwhvfFQt64CPLEKipp/wm2xCo9y04RSWmDGWB/Uo3IwIsCxc3tic/cseN3v/6z/5X@3a//5Lf0T//8t//Pv/2f0P1v8Pa/gc1CB9YAv/oTvP1TvP0jmswOklnPTSQCHzx2/PRnv4HX//Ff0j/98k@soH/4Fw5vaI0IQtBrE/NP/w7e/i7e/g@HN7wG/NM/sgAxisP7TO2YVi6A@tW/p2lIDbGskf3ZX9K0wwMGhsuWvDurjj9sbYW1EKzZcEdcDy/DrTt@kAJ4zLo9DsBrv3GbNw8WgHsLuc7jN8I2dQ/MGWsKCbW0wAt93O5oe2kG2j8CmjCa4e@BvM26YPTYgxhOyP3fpo9ppwdh3Lj6tIt9HKLD7fzb@XZsQhHW42CAOjyy30ZFPtexpgS6txTIN@kJLAw/dltIj5SzZMTmbwm/QbhqQBwrySJfL6DstFaxodND219yIp@zWHV1UWixGbL2xJOvOFD2fjxuK8EddfOi2CCVlz7QZdzskt2OSjzE0RiKBKKt@Y2MxRfCBe9LdJuSs6tNtpx7UWHw6oCJOdzWSOuEErTD8QVY5LQN70aLK7gLb9FrA9yxx8GHnT23@4AdNzc3DmrLj0UZ0rsugmErU5bKWAdxu0GBraDAVhDQbOEkuiYcCLyggTQcqBd395db0bZU1G60jXBhzVmVA5IBfUFrmNMrKROjn3iNmmjkXWX3GvkWSu4hYdeTe5XonDPa4X4VAXDuxkm8LMv9qNlXMK8Lan9M5PaOz05pvY1pJ85WpSDco15yaV1yXHxfye0m@A5q7sHzlQkF2L9hQr6vTCgS/nJCL4sV4@6gf5u/X1Y7KzWx1vAbZFbFP9hpoLBp/DMQvY06Qop14nS5ocuTtLs8nZlGu/Z8sgv8mdXRgDvf6dK3DgzETkxJM0VreODTWIMuh4ZW8NaHPvd94df@rmZP1XTR2N5LL1u7DVUnnuYgaD0VWjUvHlEo2x@hw@l569ye3XZl3bLZVmja@nYoorYYhZbn46OsyubjIxifiuTeMBBf/QJuAXNS@NFRcG3Fd61N2/LYpeFRq6b7yziJvWtFq8vC0FUe24FOSCRJQ4dOEBXofNF9/ByRoVkswSxaHygCi7RjusiRSH1tpPVEVcODLDD2C/SFDW4kiB@PCS1emvfSwhZFdifaJXh5tx318mdHpS8D@EGtVfzALoIdZnhp/SWPkbP6nuQe30zOirZKr/bz6a1t01t7n15J1g3zJc3EE0d78Pnzkg66NhgAcENG8MtkeO2za16Rs0PK2hs/hWdF@GoSu6IhQPOHlCYBNGmD@yWQD@/6zYC3NeHNt/j/fgGuome/tviIMVtbgL4ZkS9XkS6aQU7uUgXRBeAFN@qe18mtRTvzlWnZHR3Sw/PSDqK4VNxJCBVzPBZVY73WaoX4CzKP64ZeyT1ZTJSwAvfQpE@99DDwdhFlHruiwi/ErsuG9G7hXeW4KvJdoq@@LuOo6IjS06zvH7pYL7djipEd3wTo@A2R4b1Tt/ttsbJA5LX0kMk4QmHhbf6RgbuXqhkHQRPWHIimgwY9IIdCkaO4xovxwjolQrG@u2zrUav9sUqyhIdnfJEhwAfrG2icd5Os@z31WXWts/QVLcIa1r@bZdwIvsKIW7Ffl@HPY9GXc0pGGdaREqtS3rFO3ipx@b0S35KKlUxaVsnXieSXhO6rZW5L1CxkGxWW/nlNyCvMaV5RBMG1jdHyebfENPWVTkA/LDFNfaNVedyjUNcxiaYz8VMxCcu@cFMyOAvwnMKzCU9ECH3QR0ugVnlDu3Y15EVCRvx4y2qxfe4EtEW3uOjenkfcgqJWbhzIfV6nKbyZpvAqTWEnzXUN2E1yC4gSdpK0SwGL570iUETJfEM7YxD23OHxntqGS9V4HedePztl57HspZ1T5zEoZKfoPM66QCk7u87jDHEYzuMacQydx5fg2NQt5w/O41W1QAAdXonjE/rbKhzfBedx2uV@pvADzMYqXb/zeF2mAPPReiUcebaGVzv2rL@2HlUV8eOWaFR6aZQYAx4aZuvuwUt@LPwTUPukRQj8kKADRwQYOyA7jcZWi2GlA82Gn3zN27Wv@TheDU3Z4xubMRQI9yS2BlVQSiZEHzkPnLvKyCIMQ8ngIzyBQNSbx/sporlXPbMvkWOnLuNnRYHZu@kT7vmJPdB1kfA7AN4exFE28VfltYvCKsCvoxMjv0XnK3JWyRGKcDGAew9ZyNTvne9kCsv6xal9Vulvl9DrMQIsRN8KxColgnZLp4MNh7YpSWysjXeFhITibJ@8HQcvu1Ki9L6IRrSCXTPfCCbeds5QMWxXfvd72dmKh6TtqCAMvGMfrFq2bheILsagja7bslStygckbOmcLjlGR0SxzdhOAmepGy9pK95qhlZxrSSJ5tpVkxDZj5tnJ7xppb6Zl8EttT@v@7qKCSY40IgItmKuU7H0q/Yz7HfNst9XBvWKCS8S2GdY729KX5vX77ayLyhXNsm@LkAM9NIZ917jaJ3ChuXQO9iyzN@TtVcmPn5B0DLyrUTX2F9Y@yu2rfsEX@Dby76FhQutBH266znEgdlh4G1GvbZIlKl/ZbT4MSUbj5XxNaWbrL1Pq5XxfUWMIdhGw@NnF7C@W8DbhYf4SAb0Fyy3ajnuuiHzFOu6TT4ovpm5sGYdNFwltj6DcssT1D1Zv7ZeogUe5cdqplwqtqHRjUaj7tdTEVhrIe6mHafenSZYd1sCXjxGzPoeuIYraXTzw73qeL2kjHiAMcCTeRtL/Ow67rZ12ZY@f1F3IZ4Fu8VRG9dwUw34Ha2Epg6PTbZs89X6eoXriLeRrMxb4LeX9NZw1gilAyd0Hh9J8/X4iItzHh/tVgyLZj2N9PsD@wOWgc16DepgdzUTsbiMV2f14ADAZGR9wNsegLNP4bHWoRzgt8bNVex1rIlqyqvFDjg@ZH8v3JrLdwU5HJ0oSGsfQgcuynAFQtiFDYTxLAIrFkLjwCdZWmmn88EydPAwamOsqeQ4UXJEGzHb8WhsYzX0SsieqDOeLAOxUiFHKGxRZC3IWs2LWV8pV8kxyxAX99KRIeQVb7y02POTGZ9AHLocQ3lsnTK5XvphuEkkQjBZowU87ijiCEiqgezuGU2@kqFU@jm51wNBYuxPslgLXOo8RPVpki@9Oj3pgG7yitxdneNrrwkjZ2jb48DATtfO8VcGHYiANRX3Amc3P2AsLpOh8YgrlizSIlDwi8Ijajlj3q24H1wL9@6TW11uxPfB9Ygla@1olXX8/MqUV7f4bG903RqatictiR7YmrlcneRG2SfvJcg8pR/XqI1djgPH6nw7dFrLJnhFWB0M5cIjyY6pb1SieHAFGC1Ya2vAwFXRaCPTa@71klSV/gUdDJBPSkN6xEolyQIOa2ZvBzuEQVQk1lrdZysYxy@6jl/gZCL1zQHqQkvWMP5KlNFNTvTdyDL9wUZnTahgVbaqwOolvPUShK7GN3sS/uByeACLx@F27GACeHv24xtL876OCkrR/Xum3o20cloymayPOL16nuwl@8lqG95TbNHTGoSyDJPNK91kptBZnGvR@lQKsPX2daoT9FSi3flYzo/S@XGWkkPtkec2OI/nQ8twOphOCuyNdF6UQtH0jXRjiElFjDPTwfC6K1bHHU435MvSVam6ZHKN62bveiDdtlqDqFqjxtXbVO96Ll7HWuq02YgXjGuxmS6Zw9LAnHCLcrQVacxUI9Wsp/oXi8JsOC9EtLYcTl@L0aY0zs@ERXgs5BvU7bTej9Tyi2GcG3UXybTRbUc9HqadTvVieaF7K13U0pfdnh7uhIe1OB@cji6k8aJ/mVefioN0bSp4xoNcITKl1EphOhNDrWFHyau31Wazk0lVZkPOuB13B6HW1cTsxPRIMDhJiv1BKFyYmHqsmEpeRs1MstDMKTdN83bRjFUoM2/Wo40LIa54pmVTCE4yDcZgm/ML@bI2i@QDdS2vXiiFQWV4PjmvKOPJMBOSy/VRSO/d5DpaIJC/rk3z7SKlhy5a7Vh1EIhlhLnAXIY1bRSsx0tF/Wo@ST2VxVZaqKXEToRNhW@y3OCqvBDK02K12qqMW41R1LjklNscO6DKN0ItmRrmiqMYVy8tCrHzQm2SThfm005A6mnJSbcVvLqJzIolsdC6ZoJ5fmJeeeR0WWEGFxfGotm4LNyUjFuo1lcXckhazFPNlC49ZdLGVbXIlPRhvxYaqN1xMyqnNeGiUgiZhWEyP2vdxgupoShVOkNtWG8prYkpZwZMjlqkh9eNjjjLycsZnw0Vm9fMIFsVzGiyF6wxA0nqDJWyseydF5e92qTT68bL52xGfLrspprhanbMXeWMUEldUO16SpKX1WuJG1bi@cJtJ5uUr9RwuiKOK@f56TwQaMtSZRZecvObQS4kz4UQWyynbq481xeBqqfoSaUqWrDcowKZ3HmrF770aDlxyRQl/ima9uiTSWiemUxkXSw2VEUfhRU2lqt7@lFDb8WvrmYdo3BTTbcEZRm7vRoOI7dV6mZaMDQ9ELvIJeNMZcjq5/ygVLiNymouNEudK9l4obVsxMxscaLE8sVe5qKqZ@oj4Sae7dUWi2EvdiFWisMkJcYy1eqg02t25u2aUVmwVyFh0PFkz7Olpx7U42YtF7hopCK9STXYvMyo00o951lqN63iOF0actlKbBKpR4Mjajq/iCVrpiqPM@dX8cj1RC5mk5leI81ponjzJFxyQ75WX7AxI6pf526ux4bHrHe0UKefCi6ur9pM89YwwnmZup23IoXkUBcuu3PzwojW1YBWvma5a6nUUMLTlvzUrmiD5Ii5bNwsmc5smZtXTMGsDbVwNxoens@NJ315qV9SsfaAVxqltFYcCJHLtryMMmFOrbfT0pXQvgiwyUYvfyXm8tPesiGOAoP80yQv8IJRSbY750pkOh97pGBsWqTqpdZNL/r0xHbEUjsuJ4eNaqVgBuo8M2nXiuGnYtswckKjIKdCsjrJpNrnw1H6dsHXjflyUo90FGlR0QNslpqX2ldNYaD1jJxxKwyWN7lb9WoSiNyUB1LU7A65kcwVmxIbLY2rnoynopx3eotIcyJOBbAMx9eFMZdKDgZlqsyNotPUIm6Y6rlxWeqkL5JyMlmMBa7HgWh@mD7Pz7tys9Es5bu8FrrtpIORcqfHBrqpUrZXCY160UopGiqmqXpncV3lupmYzPV5JT24WITG8WIgFWGas2r@elDvqyUlnWzNpVRQqGuzaIuX1Ia4jESZK9Yz6Mcv1CQbqkSohpkxG8XcLOhRLwtXgcpiIdx0@EmQl57ahkdoL/vLclPkNaVffKpy9eakmJYHg2YkJdTZcqrGTpbGjB8XK1Q8U1G5THE@zc36tRZrjDP5cawzL3XTlYrYGXeDY6lTTs4ldtpq3V5fN8rq6OZ6lK9GO@Vllx@Em6ZUjZTnJvUEJk9zWmzkOvOMZEiD6vRJPZ9PbppMqHE@Kja6U88gftueBuWbMlsspZoSPylc96JmozQfX10oksKMAuUeQ80aleXSFJNatjS7as@l5nKZlFPGEze/ZPjieSFzY3ri2VwyU67XeF0pl8@LmSQ/ml3NijdRj7isXXXD8vDplqqoqhLQb2tKNMUGjUAjnFmmhcE5OzlPjeoX9Tg35hr55tXVJddXhJEQbZczkdaV0EomLy4XFxLfrFTGlctGnSp71Jvb2zpTrivFuFQsVOtauDDVr1qtKD/Tktc8WwiNOrPiPDW7mkxao/iFp22KfFBbiiJXnSlFRsyD7MQocTKtpEsVYxF4Wg6eetOMdtOMJ8fnkWR6IXWn4nTJJjNTD2Pk5rNuRB7HAvX2/FxqC1e93mU11Q@Op@N6JB2mLuLSldrspPtX8YV4mS82cxNTrHU7IdljsONB/TrZMBrCQj4XIv1pw2grUPmkcbieSscN5TYTu9RlDxsTUpTQuuIrTLEfvilddLVZen7VXGSgyxHjpAob1hZqcxIbqvlLI3XZerqMxXqNTn4ICU/6t31BbnhS3Y54LSkl6vbmsjnMViZNZnB9cxWtNPKe2DKonz8JWv@cjy/qyzLLilK8Ny1M5sFxUYidxy7LgnIxL1UbktiL1ALXyrm6pDJqtM8mJW42namMZxFOxbI9KdUoqXqmIeSjolbhGWbeujXLrZvYZeCcvWZroxkbMK5mDCu1VXnRLrXbgS6VmhqX41aNm2Y9eTPZrg2qwrnClFrVwlJbFLMBo5EspaXLyWwxLi5kPXgrFM/TSkWQOTBLwpFeXW8Ml6lph2pJ82I6FYveBvIgQYahxGftEC8Kxrg3HzDFq0lemQ8mw6buGc2Zque2PQ/H@82@wQjFYr1UmGX1sHZhDFQqEhEC@ZY@jhrVp9GikDYz/WZDCaXjzV6nnG8zV3XpMn6drt1GxXCFKTyJ8VYtwgrFcEtguKo2mprQIgm9IVVcsF1dUESdj07KT@HsZOLpLqYT0zO@jZ5fxlq9YZqbCrwnmOxoT/y8eaGwcikq9oxyaza9ybXAQlSb04ZK5W4b4@ClnJdq@Wb5ashVktWlyaTiLeEm1GvrnKRK02rQDF8UxF5UkDLZ2@Egky88Fdi29MTOOEW/vg7m8hwVlTwpU@sqTPN6fK0uA7yYbJdjV7PuMj3qlyQxXwhk9HY10q1d8koWmlH5qciOm7nz4m23o/QZSVPLtSrLUreRQLZ1U33ipt3ryrKuzfN67yJZUYI3UkHVKjdNLnOtM6VoKnedHlRv04tYpKIrHbHei9XVkec8qAl8Ui1GqKg4FVPNFtMQ5SAXnS87/FBkuNvWcBjLM8uIsWSSqjEbxHrLeOd8xLVuS9p5fTFkzkfz20rqhpuIHo6rCGPq2lxWwufnLc/l4rxR6CmNgiQw/GgxMPKpiXgx61xHkp7YmK17st1mf16s9MatLBPtdGJcLRhshcynbmVhXJeoZqaYD0YzC3MuZYeT0jyWHycjtcW8cR0KDW8H83KsFqmG59xUG2ZT41wvzGg3RlSd1/O9XErMSleScbXsCCMqspyUCrlY1hMW@XalfctKWeap1lXMfk@qX94EaxFGCOfLldntbSbJjKLSIFtQzqFNnPFX80Vt0B52rstGUKa0cttTiCwjy9rtdamrVloXV/3OrBeNVvR8cxCfLNvjqlz1jJeNQkc7z1RGSmZ5AwIXqcbDg4aSbbTkm0yVLVNmpJWcgQ3OpYryoscUwuylpLIX89F5/GbUigzbw2Z6Wm3Ph4NILRrWJuIyaraewhOxEW1fjGqM0GnP@p7AOaXVloub7HVIL5Zm46JZ0cRLNhYo3g4bo@yk4RmlL3MdM91ix51AqzibeNJhsApiV814oNS5HKQKw/NrI38diFP1nLyYxAbnkXNPBRqTycAox5pKQJkyLUZpzqbicMTypQzf1OedRq7YLXUDMWbskaMz8zLydNGu3PLmOKQylLGIdGe8J58FCyIjt8M1T9McsyPoi7A30@Cl2gsGDPWmVhPMtBYdNoJxMZTTm6rWnGuDZkC@Po8OZ4J8OaBS4rIbUhrVVrc0X8668WGoy9emjWTuRm0F0@q4Pzd0LhK/DDT5p8pID5bNcaXYEFLq9YjnpZlnrqQyV3ptSnV7pWS3lXuaSNNmqJwMJRc3XTY0uZ0OOHV5k20HBpVOsi/Nqq3QsjoLprrnnFodyeORHmDYelPNDmPzRl68pC6WWXHRj12nKs1Q43IQHwaV3rBWYRfDsiwJt7fGhCu0e8VrrlsIN1PX8WFeMpJitBGXLgbMvNQp30bSXTHEUp5@YcQE0kUheJG98ZgXghJ@kpdcyVzGJXVRasidWm@aHBe7g8aklMozKS4wPZ@XR8F8lQlO@NQolrnU27pCidlwct4oX0WM/m3SbIa0SmAaG99W5N5NoFvp88KIjcRAB191O7eLRrKamhXbpXzNSKq9pejRZ5fqeSGXS6lUXmqVnownXpMmyVCjXGxfP10n9V493DGNAjd/EpnFQi1fpAVh0U4WjGGpeVFTC1F21E1dRa/73aLa0Cpy8JIS4tHhTZRRa8LFhBVDlWQo99Q8F54K00hVG6qmUM/ecmapCsquEG6Ux@3ZaJnus9I8GMreGOVed3wLtXWwpAKTfLXdrUoDdT6rXpjNy@Coxg2bM2UYUfmxJ5SNl8s81wtiJyx8o6kjTbnsmTe10vRSZ5j@MjIRx@fipUwVA@NeslCNXAT48/N2Jt7gRk9FMRC7Ck2Ss0C5euVRw@I4U@iNFDY9rA7Eaxm6DK1IZXDB1kpyo3c7Sd/EFzVq2e5IcfWiNdMu08NZZjgd1BvzIHSv6s2iYdSqN2a3MA10LqJKp9zv1jO59LWQ5nkjWlbT2fJwPGl2RrN8KEwNcsGbwVX0Qu5FhtGCuGhfTsbxysWykO7nQ562ehEz27ypPJWVwVOpY5qdp6jcrF1fMK1UVFDZp0XUvOm3GIPKx0bZ85AYXRb6XLShjqaTSbdcVbXConJ9BWyOBoL18w6THLeuK2azmxeFm3wDLP0LTSzUbi7GtfObfHfSVSklCOKbZvTL86KRu8kMb7lZobroyJxnWL6clcPRsBTveKbhUak/yYTDrejoojTNZcZ6ZH4FWr9XWVSKYrV0RXGjq3Z26LmQOC6mXy2b01A1Kd5EOlczaRYKZ5JztR@LNdj59cW5cB3rjAuzUeOC610zs9v40BjxDb6aFDSpTKWexsFFZm5m2XD2MpK/uRYHkVk3OwkUkrNaqxAx4yWp1Qo9zaqzoVjKcVJ9Pp0FKrnytamGwvPm9e3wEkohTAm9@XU2Kl6FxC4rL2/Tek7rqA0@yTIXTGDWaF57tJ76VBI9w0ogFxxHsuy8wkPP@DY1uehGOo2B0jpP5eN9qhsSsp66ESncRp5unq5k/WbgiY5A5cSk6vT6CkySjtmoh@bXUrzNLZvpWIvv5JZc9pJJhvL5SbwQCFwU48U2ZdTCI5CWp1ng5iKjBK4rzXpo4smUMvNuv3bbqKZnV7HbNjeqtGrTC@yMBRl2JpUH1cailJs3ZDGSHVazUoryFK5nRjk@lqqZZlZnKl0pFxoM8@e5c3FyKUzmWdXD9gqNxfRpMhJjF1cKL@pqrmr2k0KwHRsG50JhnHy6bFKLPJ@94NKxZkwfysLFoNQwBsa0NZbkZOgpPPeY1UFFvgxnqvUbddDol0q6kL4KRA0xM6yNIreNwbwzFbPdC0oy41NBmZ@XIqaaWuTkm8bV9UW3xi6ESuyilNPnbIfJPdXYqck0YrVKvdcp6XJxAA2np93QtJgCKsXsa9cUP@4X2FkzedmN9Yz0ORsrXszLDbnkYa@z1UEmYEx1D9MflQOZpZa9CEqzaK96fTli9fS02/dcVqLM7SClzUpU2OwGW7wxjFclrt1uMuNsdWkYV7FGx3N5rTBiNXAbTeWXXL0THHcn/XasPTqfPrXbV0@dZi0PxXnjESO1qyeqd32ZN6JSXOC6jVS6mNSmY/ZCH1Wl0KiotRuBtuRpzzOF2VPgks0NCh2uVOovlynhQm@pscyoc5XmF4NGrEkFs2W2exsUxxeNzFM7158MhHRxLgRvtLzhuQmV5pNzPRaNcKH4lDeCzdGo6YklFdkTDfYX/UAqO41kmK5ebVHZsifd0jSoBdXbCF9ijFC3pJhGI1qvZePVdC6dL15mb6RivFbgb2487etCOpusRy4u@8PQZZszUkzqqj@oBahBMT3sMqYZm8g1OWdkz/XMvH87vB5NOrPotGi0l@olP5F7I07ix8NWUY1GktfNp3CZDWavmOztUlED0fA8TnUFqXvBKNXhTSsmZ/NMW@lDBzoD8j@8uZrogqQb/XgLcn61VKPpRrnX1PNKvwIUKp3JWJBGcXnYF4O3VJWpxXLRlnIpCeV2dRRtd@Sb@kUwKk3m0H9tZ5aXUoaBUm@0a/0JexPJgukaCj0VWv3R9bTUNKrhTLNerISo5lM1I3GFbLHYvDW7XKnM9nJTsxGN5bOcMEoNS9lFqpMqzHJCo5X3DDyBeleY5ppJJdvs8sZ8ccvGWT0pDajIIHKVkjKcOQs3JT2UvuiXg7xS0Obli9h4VK1cBFIX2WtJG@ps6jq5uiLNRXwkhxc9KZk8bxba6R6VvE5nBoGmZAhV1TMrELBUTuF//7OPChF1XSVg1FSTu/ixL0P8f4u71q02kiT9m3qKpLCNZEo3bPd0I6BbgLA1i4FBwm4fTGMhlaDakkqtkgCNzY/dH/sC@wD7cPMgs/FFZGZV6QLMzJ4zM6dNKS@RkZGRkZGRmRHazUX5AccT7HkCz9tTfidw2SfpSKCj31dLgGTPPcUL4Q1phM828wgEg6PF8vTZYq5k3AnwH/jxUC/ZgWEndRDqDlHZorEc9B9CgE88@QQF52D8PPl5tEH/EQ6eAUlk4hd1GaZN9lHcmCLw8wE/qMXzcuLIM1NKYgMEacia/Q7R03Ofw6vCC6rIR8DVo/3svGP9YjlVn5CLBn32NOLm8i5X1V4xACkNQkYT6dY3g8MOWczB2gOh7ZqF0o/FH35i/x6q74283tlP597L1par/FHQ7Pei8fC2/fUqvL7pqK4a/H5515r89Q@l3rxW8Gi0/kJ8o5Z@2Cqwp@o/sZvPn9i59TPjmpSDCMDTF3tvhCfUVaWsm6vyssryh4d/NtzyDJeqlz3DheLko3f2w/lWf6tY7p31z8v9tbXsaG1rtFZayyDhRSlbHoz1TcSz0Tm/2i@8VO/N03oEfsHd37CjjsN@6zpcjdRd1W@l3pywRzMzgXrNQXI@3fitUThMpnTAT81eaiLOJuGUuDlVMwhNudFk4OPoznol6IbEv/hnafzD6/JsPnq4tAQXGmV9dyLZgW/OYHzZDVobzhLTE0fgeE6/saGdwrQU@HZpidMCSRRcVBBlkF02ua1wMNGVAylyYfqymQC5ncHZatZ7SklT6pJ48gJh@oZUTIoIeVPFFYHmo9GsYIXvA79vz0HhxydbhpcTtWzyjMcflAffsN@di5EK2EsP/dlUuij7wFBZ7XGCU88CPHrjqwTbq5K19Pu4N@Dz57zgqymCGMQXg2YwtDXz0fgSr3tVCcQIDNIYAXzcwyPcTXPkJ4fGjAUuvvHjK/QH8I45kBQh3GoiWj3JRjw@ALx2yHWWJMh1Ro1CuVgpaOi63I2sHmoiHPzIrw5WNxTfgytTEh@JlhO5v1Mu@rogu0fZveboekH2NWCPo0XZQ8pG6OsF2QFly5vI@fkh5ctJ/4ICI9zyJHa9GIUXo2bQzYhDD7gCuReBnVFra4awlgWUDIyMR7q@0q5R1LKMjjBbir1ofjJbSQGwdEZPHvyOuYVz4ec3I3yRaFNoor6pRxvTlyOJxBfcEoldtJ99mYKvEgjQ/CNRqmbzTeMy2rajKf7J07JzhdEmYr1S378/hJlmxDT/lc4N98kI4R5uoodCrRiOROaNx1Uq/VVXml9Hu45JSjdzRyLuh5mU67EIkbkVz@tO0G9TGwR4OZmMK09Z9XOcchadqw0rPWI6yrR4nI7rM9yDG1E8Iz11GX@2nk7VJvieajZpRb6MhQX8hDXLM@SMbOlcuvQ2lbbUnOKzVopn9Cz9Rzv7tN6sEH48qZk2ZRG0LVINtzWCc9BryrgmZYIAe7a6IemIIxykgQULgIk/vQsCMNokHLCyGTFu1sSgn5c3qSTni@uvPb5iLkXuYzIZYfUUOv0/TC4QTi/ZY4RWTIskNYc0M8Vtv0Gv7ekpN9U9kfTzO3cmj5pXf14FjmqWn5jrfqZVckMVlXXcVFb3j8uhf44y3@LhS@k7UWaxrDCDbjjxKSx4v4DQjzJZugvr5ypFcaDAkuGRJYmdEM5flOKr9RcmxVy7lLm9UAMDVuV0PnAWgCaDFOVkLU/rXNux6NTeFy9GRrnxYi0MEY2FK0hlLztJcY7t3D4v3slU6zqKKZLMwUt2aJhDg1nQMbotqcGmXr51gWEWIoOeNKevwrCdMQqTVhgYgvHQQYU8cWdl1SpRL@PmqTmt9Kor7eXDrLtlSlnWSbyuUAKUT82bQOLlFU@bMqZNQr8JIg64zflYjagp8/oAlxVF@qiN6XSUtirQ0txKRuLDJxl7rtRynlfilHhwd5t9XAzlsAO8td50kW4HAmW2aaMd@7fkMbifY2UQH57au@W35NYlKAd56MR20M0tyGzZYrO56aIZy/D3f19ZLoyjYeEy6Bf8/g0p1ZcTZ0X5fYn8uKHGo07uR1wUrpy8/aClCd/L5kuIxCY0Umgt3/dvMyhDmjO8iLpZR3zS8aXFkgO/xHxvvOvftEnrF48tgzC6438ntFko5seDUcg5uiH2Xae@B99jf6pFfkWkdwwanU2GE5fJ4H2BpE7krmSuJApSCT6XswkQZ6jJAtf97LoYPyCq75OenTtR3m@2roEEeO@7bKdouJiT753IDD18rYEUeLxCn13xMjHgu6NogrWTaMK/qfv4XcKHpPAVV/C93qc4fCEYOd0wHIDJcRUU9TeJAEL4pXpjr3pyktfxoeTGOm65yz1mPBFkh3UcrsFe48VtdbgLlEFZQmcBW9rbioGz/GUaoVlNJkyFW5BTaAV/hNKDXIl/zXTDls9KcSYJP3fSvyLQsqi9egxIjwLt4mqZRLWcqWYKJ0ix9Cg1mq0WHEG893shYbzrd7uEtNBiKSYHPkER0/6abT86Q5vnFnnJz83k51L5eckXpOJS@db1MC60kSzkrnyLy90rNy7mzbS1pajTtUP2LpUPhwm8yw@VjfK0SQviwtt2KIUrbcZmKiOXyPltzuhLznKqjmVwm38m@Zq/1/XIWyxTZX9Jt4@/jh4gn30w6CeLU1ya7wfdn8X8aHNYwiq4VZLqGG9mO5mU2iCixUmOxAQxMU/b7a0YylrJSByeM@725i9uXpukfs5Mo5HlFwIzE2vOHElQidtcY8Ld8UpC7XD2cgIEwwSjKTNzt03lia48SYBFqWXTrGM8haYnOHVteopv4Vr3d/xjJnsaOVNuZX7mkmB@J52XlxZpArHQXXbnkyktTUbDsS@JulMPrCJx25NpiPOFxGGIHWjrGpLCtunLe5BOOO63l62cSAoKIylm6G5zNKXjAiXDvouGEJn3zt8LL523zR5phV3/TlWgUzfZU7@Temwz8qNRhIBG1MGhisaDQTfQft3ULT/nkH6W1t/gMUIMMaE05J0aHohKeQ9f@nEMVcqrI0C@xTvDOCMaX11Rw7AEI3Q8idZOQCBHeafSn7BnYnaDti5PXnw1hh9XCOAubfsSSMjIyexhywO0tLxjHhZJVzsyv/sjUoGo4yH7PISr1Q3H@cs4aH3dfavWi8U/lYqvSgmSGVN1Mf/qtaolVCSTsV4sFYtvSq8dZzccTORpY6aVBazXOQD01AEW@g/Em/4NQrs7FVoxuGBEqn/kD2/8dt5xTvw224Avx0wRsPIY5OobP69IId0K/u5J3e1FnqJt1zXEC/5ifRbftS12rOE5eEM08Ie9YCQvjcKboA0CmndTnbDbDW/ZEI0nS0IPVOr5IyLKy6xKo8R@aTUurLuwu1iiBmI@sAO/y/CG/UhrMpCeGsD9Pj8AcuBEERCSjfXbU5hQe61uM@iBneYgAC9LMQUMAtS19rjlP4iDw0j8gzgo3bF22BrDM2/TjEyBpF/Ic4Wmuz8MSPrGBOZR4WoJ3GmAG@9qdVU/2m98rJxUFX0fnxx9qO1V99TOJ9V4V1W7R8efOIiXend0QNKlriqHe5R62Dip7Zw2jijBrdSppssZTuXwk6r@enxSrdfV0YmqvT8@qBE0An9SOWzUqnVP1Q53D05psX7rKYKgDo8a6qD2vtagYo0jj1s11Zy4njraV@@rJ7vv6Gdlp3ZQa3ziFvdrjUM0tk@tVdRx5aRR2z09qJyo49OT46N6VaFjzl6tvntQqb2v7uWpfWpTVT9UDxuq/q5ycDDV0aOPh9UTIJ/q5U6VsKzsHFS5Je7nXu2kuttAh@KvXSIeIXjgqfpxdbeGj@qvVepO5eSTp4HWq385pUKUqfYq7ytvqXNO5hGq0Ljsnp5U3wNpokT9dKfeqDVOG1X19uhoj2ldr558qO1W62XlHBzVmWCn9aqnEN6WmyYYRC3Kp@@d03qN6VY7bNCacXrcqB0dZmmQPxJhCMsKVd1jAh8dSm@JSEcnnwAVdOAB8NTHd1VKPwFNmVoVUKFOVNttJItRg0TERrKb6rD69qD2tnq4W0X2EcB8rNWrWRqwWh0FCCba/VihRk@51xgnwks@iVkdw7keD6eq7avK3ocaMNeliQPqNc0tTLbdd5rmNJcLztwjtwcP8GZP@bQp5GEn8btHe1XS@CQQjBunn9Ki82P68C6VRwuNzaSf@hSU16qLtn85vroI@p0QW3NbTU6we9GVhzhLWUQi/uw8ENddH5RzhZWVi4sPlQva59YvLrLeU2qm0HishvbC@lCprO5jN2y2eZufsi0lCbX9Qvt698TxctLW8sIaH7KqUGj7uhoeLwKwMRPpoAQErA3JyK8am32VaJKPmNO2Io6YMW0sMsebYUT/9L/HP2RtSCSQcJZ7C4UC9rCMBiKfKIs/NcJBQXRkEL4HEHS4yXzk@1@vMsVkc9jyawNV1tThsiPaBl5lso9Uv/SvpqrnpuszsnhrysqKcQdv3LSDMUP@pUmm9Ljkh9yzjJj2@E/WYMMNkVKYlab4Iau@fZJ5IdXhX1RshdmydSXO4UDeV36tfcRmrrj@ujyV/s6my9zCq3PEtqH17ozrnfOfd@dSgCZYgO0XkSSYyJFqoZCoQ1oZ65O2MHzVX6PQbdCmNRVL9bXPyzo85Iu74GR9WoyHwV0SexLDb08q73dO9/dJcgLb1z@@@dMPZUd73B@OfvXk7ye0wxE9QV3Som8DUtM4KzFLdknv2Z8JlpOI7oPRQ0FEoDSDxolNUmmt50zRESS@hpiB0N0IEQb6CLLhIkjA0FV4n@8vO4Zf585MzQCZVFez6E2veccafpNUJeaBlnjJ7E541O7wD2Db6W@muO2QZiDNYn5vMJoQ59LmguWeu28cDvDehp8Vo0jeNXw8aJo7SEIYyEz2woA3@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@SCOR1WTXYPUfU7PCeGUuR9qUBpx1oEnCet3XMpkt/dIvloivQ2YdIDE1lnrMbEzSibZFWjTDCN5snqvMie2uxZzMl@NVif9r/2kfwZV9MXKZEPhUBKumCNa/eNzkYVPdp/XbjxtdA1u10@7U@@1VpyXklTHO8c6dWsNN/HsUUIY3zFtolrUMxlZqtr0h0DY8Gt7ngjv5wWzndcxPTiPYMHLFuntJ/v3BDAF6ZugOr3M99a0TakIVs67lRX/Alc9d@fcKXtjNvUacIOUrBhVmtBgFl6E24pDk72xi/lFsdXD7dIM3p9jZ/2Rz3mv1Osxd0J3zr9Pfwul@I@uNokB9MHNd109ZAOAKHixTCfeSrj0G/Hd5GaoemAwxJ9cPT@nHa8JewfO2K5UupP1MbaodbdmbAd@AzKQo7Ixoav6wmOkT8MDb3sJ1QW1rYrDVBAhxTDZmBqN2e1YzfHp6qt37fH5I@eMx3LtVB0PL7JD5ImeJbmNG1SBoU30frdd262ofuwpadsvIDNupY256jG9DQPLBWhqYiITzUYRVhm58QqydsgvnZDsf9ahuj0nU40N6AYDSFsikmzs646zmI3fix1niHzbhszNk2Q8uasfXBliiqU0@MtdSZYbM/mhBRnGnjDaH9mO0mr9gZEEF0FpOTN3U9BG9vw@zXjairn2jwtBTgFYSmqh/cIFgcm@GeMkZ8z1abzWK6lbV/RU/C1xnRkRo9Jx49DzFD855685Nq@OBdddxttmiHpepjVH/1ivTAnTAaoej7ilLF9VKplCu9gon2tF7J80TAfyaCmOPU3h8fnTSIkNpFvmEMu2aC@By0S25jETlyCN1Fvf8CgWzKk8Rc/8LEgwpu/Pi6ZTmxcDdcGvtWE@Ze6mGUVofZJAuTfDjkwGHwBkUslJqO1CqcHiBEHwtJtJSA7nHoMh18TJYWiyd78@MKX4Bbl/iqi/PQL1yZ00gA@HecRrWGvDNoa7f3NCY9v2exD0ZmdW9KAWc65pklmNhSiTlWvVVoSUS9bBJO28cdiQjRA3rRTWtIsqV5QyyHKyzGJRbxDMumrO1N8zLoBjQHCK/WdYgFR8SVGQg2QSQjojk84jbWDhYkxmVOtAKaXe2wZ4sKVo5jncHp9EE0aYVq5Yq22dhpRQPfb3OkhPFAQgEgP0@zvEsrh7iJ24hjBDgrRb43OSRhg5AsJPvGXfiOha@/Sxlzx/SGuMq4F2xcY1svgKhH9RFPUkRsy8zZYXsK57xZHvYmMQTqZkGIBY7@CMTAw6EUYUXjzQzBX8wuHtxRdXm8p/0AoiIHI4oG6QzAklNdP51hwKPv@nOmgDDplkVgysWgQUb8ZMl3ygaW/oH@4t4pnKZlpI/UuUnWEnM/QAhNsQ2E6irEvyicNxSTM0KfzwhnHBfewSUvwZsuWZotSaVsAJFEyfU5MHNzYb6aDzOnYerDylr/hh22oRazhfRCvEGHJB9BiLj7b0MjetmtXDeUAybb@6tueIm4TSQpqDX8mXjxwCaTeQeWInQyV5wIpuNNbZouadT12yaju6hNmh/@tto0Fovtz30ZKJ2xJXOJfZYpXrt4OvEn/tEzij/dVPAqaB1T0auAnqSS7AZYV4PUKe6GimcmbuIky@uW01V6qSqlqSoauXSVy1SVdSf2VDo1uqgB0Y@/6Z4ZvYRvJfEIqC07QEWn17yT3U2RHdCxmQYhI1Me8dbPNYOg4FlLWZ92KH7uxC6aU8f20ob5yVfw@Ma3@8zlkFfFdLyDO3N1j8UAl0rlT9gNeD@jO5TVZOAf1v1z1iCj@7XJVfoJSWU7LBlOqttDvNXKJFvJbqiVQVNODVEqwsKWbPqMaYBTepf@/1JldAO5JLJSCG51tSgkwrPr5TPaysqwGDlYdOKVmX8lBByNoCPym6@MyTKQyaTmlZHcFqZ8zshuAoV0AcctOeL/MyK9TlKxoiREQx0KH8KYaiXPv6PtGZ8xMwhef6zFWieKT2MrPTTyZ3HL52bVSPdiYenppWRemcSqYqnwUGFDbEunhYUXrzZMOtgQIO@keIJ0BzASa9KZJXg1EpKxlhKM2Nlp2ApEQqXJlhC6UtebI4DTQ26Q86Z65SRcmeseTi8jTmrlTDFJJvELYdrVcwlkJ4CyTqoW6L9owHHdMTmxF5YrSTk97Is4wsIy4/4QW9jCZtwfYgspnBj2h9nCxDK0pOX603yRGgkhAS4l6h0D25SSMshk3CVL3U2VYoQm50lf5n43MwfbhFTVtk5nRlWyJNKhS9Jt8J87GZgV7Wg0xY5EvDM7Gudxb2mNa33129Yjs@693SJtu@klQUZzOhABOm1a4DE6zyJktq1AEluMYHrP3JO7m@zRflU2LLwHRdSuq@v0694UWLOqFLOzCqXx3h8jvzkX@dxsFIV4i7UxGx/e3i7TWOPCUzhso7TrzDnxdR7Bai2BVbp3iRFKk3gBpNyTIOWeAKmQgKQn9itaL/lzZYg4df5jID5/noXBf36jjZSGQZK2HcCIjX3wbXPyGMxlUrZW@E5dU26V2QqxnvwYjJ@nYXBc0Gt7GqcTr5uwuv3VH4bTUTkWUjbNK3MwslitzKLlAS2W2rzf1eWMqsR72/zXy@vA7gRWHh9p8WOsK@Mq8bU9BFpJe9W3wOL5X1pAPy8xrOn5IIinzDCkLTv/4HTIgxBiYZKnYrZCQpCl96E6I02Ih3OnhR/vVqe9HyPg6cJq2Ud78osYfBJGpxJ1TSRWiuPMFi4WTma1MvJt3vbs0fZX5rY/CAek43TmIsDle7Dji1FqSqTHqunU1vpJa9nc9Wy2X0m9bSo2ydMn@YuZrq9T1/EwnSZ137/Vq/9DkHVfzAj8E5r8meGRBUg@n4skDtqb2ril@uPepT90njLVpUYef2SPtJhzHWdlRVVatGXWnvFhFWtx@D5fNwk1GIwQqfEA5zWRXO7E5IaNzBcGni7bDm/7XDrvogm20fb8Zl@7ytcL5tUQ5xe2rIfwnXjcxS0E/RYROvIT5s8vEpO67esc3Eh@gKzl@WMPrkabGgsvbkmjJbpmZpLe00rqAgXHajVcamNaUTG8g8PQl6KZa32JFPPsfBPYU7SnhxQiYuJFTeoN7xToh3l0YzExxwNLSjs0TyDlPHXLWrmfoG5Nnqpu/RsoOT2gTuJbaw96gd14VKhNb/KdvxcKNjBjb47rlg@N/f2Uw5PLidkV9Pzhm2KxCCc4l82ITy1S3nBwShyEhXTpAmzihcHtn4cfLguoikMLRCbYMIeZfhR2SdRE@XB4JdEogAMVRWkcTYBPcDQxpvUmEe4B9pw@XuX8HklJ8cDTVnyNM7CX2z80mPkYJIjnb6gv6CD690V1xn0xot82ZcugoZj7ZlQbauiNa67JEXmQ0IFHHXsljYHxvlm/WsDBx9b2N2eJz8DluSCHi89@i58huu/8bjf01Mdw2G0vu/I6NF1hfz9ZoShFcJVQJk/E4Ys95d8E3UQIZxQBbmHXz3fDKwaHE3D9bJHfMg39AU7SMljHTvyr6t0g45795hJjUpfX0M015Z7jec@VS0uUy0foj4OVgBmE9pNK95qDTIvpNF2Y1kD9lir@IoxelTxVl9vBsKfsUpdxmSOTKpIVvzBCs8dLg6jz0c3/Hgb9DHUd2Q6ey/HTbx5e7smC4pa47ue7Ugc0LAoMjRNC9Dytxn0ZTqf@@f/Bug3LAR43so3XPolN@BtL9sMY4zGz1M2o06HpJZb4beNqzIBjUZkr8S0FkEYP7ND/A7EKMqudaFUCrOCqTX3Sb6UQOVs/99TqeNT5cZUg/Et9dMwM1NOP6IlrE/@Ro2m9P@Y43rE8YzMcLlDMyh1UuEAFx3ne2vrjNlOpVNSzwdqaqlR26COXU5WditpDws6O2qPfO/j9Ymv9zZuy3Jzby36jxB2TeK92CAYvQWu0Edijn5S3hR0VtlIY4meFrWde@dnF1uZ2OSqcVXbOC4Ur@vrbf/733/7rfwoV/eN/8WOHf5z9Zgvl8/nCs9a3Zy/uy/h9tne@@uzy7NngfPWqDC77Pw)

Agda is another language from Haskell/Curry family. It supports Latex-style [literate programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming).

Installing on Fedora:

```
sudo yum install Agda
sudo yum install Agda-stdlib
```

Compiling:

```
agda -i /usr/share/Agda-stdlib -c x.lagda
```

Polyglot must have name `x.lagda`.

The code is based on hello world from [here](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual2.Compilation):

```
\begin{code}  
{-x                  





-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --9ss
\end{code}
```

Currently Agda has a [bug](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2781) which makes impossible to have tabs in a text section of `.lagda` file, so
I moved Whitespace into Agda comment. For Whitespace to reach its main code lines before it should have at least two spaces. This rule is not strict -
eg. lines 18 and 75 do not have spaces, but Whitespace still works.

Spaces around `=` are important for Agda. Haskell 98 (Hugs) sees Agda code, but it is inside `{- -}` for Hugs. `x` after `{-` is for SILOS.

Removed `w` from line 115 to fix Grass. `mxf` on line 79 is for evil. 
Could not add spaces to Monkeys code, so moved it below Agda. Moved ChuckScript to line 80 to fix Retina.

Comment: @WheatWizard It works in Emotinomicon. It takes about 2-3 minutes for online interpreter to display the number. Or you can use [node.js version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142855) which is faster.

Comment: Agda is on TIO now. https://tio.run/##S0xPSfz/P78gNU8hM7cgv6hEwdOfiys3MTNPwVahqDRPQaOgtCS4pEhBySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ8/9/AA

Comment: More on Agda is in [answer 165](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152233).

Answer (score 9):

## 162. [Julia 0.5](https://julialang.org/), 7863 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x        xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`============================================================                                                x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈ +-------+ 
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/| 
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/| 
♈|       |
♈+-------+---  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#                                     _
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

# + 
#+
#  +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"5""6027""ing"ye re h  do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizechar*
More 91 of thiset of re red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   @125iRE                                     _
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )==(2,   )?1_58+4:17   )#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001849

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkhj4uVL3D@5LMMEuZBJA4kGCD4BAFYqPLnZXFbkkq2p6QBQqkUgAWQQy0ZkACRSLbbu6s9E@ZHfS7GhtNCttz6x0dmt2@rCmuzOTbNfszE5fZfsjej@und38gzl3j8gXHiRrRjIdSCAjIzw8PDw8PDzeLd3r/eY3CfywE6c/7fadERuZ3oi1XevKdDX2bMqe6pZXLKxLEkLV3O54YNojryQlWJ4xyzasNryzkXNp2tZH0wX/AmND1@m6@oCNevqImZ6hD02POePRcDxiTmdxtHXGDgbOByuDMQeW3QWwkekOXXNE4RuMvbb7@qDV1mdCijMJDl0I99i@2f80@DRihjMY6HbbA8hNxl46rmcivGF6noPRtxibHJjGDNJtANVdy3lRe/XlTNAO@xIo1Id9c8L0ljdydWNkOTayJMfOXr0@O5mJkM@zN@eHh7O@BfZ1xrHZ4di4jAURq09cpz02kA2jngnByLqO1Tc9yYAsVtlQFJiGDpZgrqm3OZjUcVyGUdjgss8sZgyHrNXXe5rB@hbAHua2mYmcZh8hvN/z2GQ4YJ41ACyeMzCjtHjMNs0284amYXUsgyhg5mRk2h7k2NOYBbRfW/0@a5t9iBCSZaQBGRt7ES9OhCa1HYnBxxjOZCJ4WzUBxjZ9RphDKAhkhIPlBlzx@XHt6sMhEAnMPAPCR9YAxMwaJT1m6p6FggxRPNNuEw@HgYg7TLejuWRXls50oHfsEm7PdLFANcLLeqZrAko9EDLl2rVGwAJkcY2dmLrLzl3TVOPiHksSEnMwhRFmRKMi3N1NHhwfJqEoeQxNH46khLt@/ntfSTrTKmy1WYZvRZbL0sGrfXazeoFuLt1Q3ENX0VVW@Y552YsLE76TfCvbdW8lwCoBV/os6wxHWT0zBAIzIyAwq6MTXZmrgjbsRxJmuzNlEREwDtWG0mBHNnuTppwZY9fFGhwyVb@ETPcduwv8hMy6Yxv5YbPNHBSB4UAFTDPzCrgGIk9l5FwTh897FhSah0USqUxcDxFDQROB7AmO@ul6Tn9McBDTG6EAAlcgKmI86rA3rKNbfYwC4YiKU@2a3rg/wjhju40lD3rGbGvMJ8Nw2gg0cK4gOR2QkgfUp0GkFhJRAAwF4VBWMeiHf/bn7W4X8NQMw3HbQlzfsLZjkMbUiVhQQwwF1rH1PpEFcGlMnUeHBK70vtXWR5i8PRVJEBGU6rUz7reZAwm61xZUrZ5@BdWx0zGNkcmFnCvZNBvol1x3WFxyIeMDvQUFSwlQ2pTtDHu6B6VkmFKCZCYzGI862ywzPGBJL/tOeVJSnqxcmECcqqlrq9lstwwCp62RF7wl75KcN7WYdvRGuudYbWk4HfUcu8AyBpONijM0bSUZw5FMJ91WUtVQpylq2aoYWsey20pyF2SxCgkn1bJRMepWqVGeiR5NEtBcIxqsrqZiqLIEKocqxVV2oFu2NpyyNxnhioQ5XhNZjsFaxBsZM@t3xT0S1MigXDooIKCHNK9vmkMlp@VVVBMItzDfGLAopzM4RIZLViOVTCRT0awTBshpLKNYWc8tB9VWf9jDBgaYYntDUN8uyq6hg/R4qMVH0NKnWYvkmlQ/aBbSiddm0jVZCxSpL0dUJXmVw/gZVJQCQ1iFfLh4jTbbkQoNygDq9Mib08p95xoSJtqwDQMVYmPieheKCCLzDNV4hniK5BPP2qUNigWxtUy2nWlZUBmw2oFuF7IfySOArxc4DGDjlSWigwb6FLAYvE0MKw6zOlCnBqAm3CkzTNQ9oIRM3rBgImOqhx7YOGjt5DKFYjFe1@aq2sjN1jI/BmX9MXtnjcLMRysVKhzWMa9ZX7e7Y72LZpYNUXTDMIcjobAgJ94IVNJsu0OeGdGIal5PWn06mzY1JqJ5jaSByp6XnmgSddQywtDK9EGpMl2YiqxtuaCe@tPZ1AHgaiZx@T2CxAh4Ly8hwbcEQMjMiWmMR6DdQJCve5bRA9lF6myuH3ljNJs8eEVTBw2f6QRJIzH56uOCpGUDLyRjKYoMlug8HmhkEVU15kGFH/W4G7PuDRYgdgISoUGI@GpZXQPZuwfnwLGdBUiBkQFaBImH8HIAi@wMrUFowHzziyprYCIGRQRlBtoDaj7IX280GnolaC@sUW/c0kBSsufu9Gh0bKOwZEfu1Bo53N3qOy1Qzx7Uz6yfQtYYt6zJTIbILyjDD550BYZYx2MVaMG/HYPUKcmOB4qT/PcQOBIkkwInFPxXBkAC0oBRSscjlXwISuVsahuKrFFV0qDSyWkmY8WVVXBgrIAve84AtRB7SwYCWnzPXNBcHdBWQveT6tcXNnlBG0D2XTKpfXAsW7lJrqysJEvJKmj4lZUn4NpF1xN0pcD1hFwZciGchi6KkSYXhtYpBvo1krd1H/NEbWCxTbB1@mgNFb1eKq030no9L54FfKqg6kCzAXQGH4AnqVYq6FRVuXoNGdVanXju91A7nxmuNRRM@Eq/0vm74MI6scEaDB0XDdkyNrZ382RQcaE1BOPV6Clu8qKeu2hc3Fy0Uxe3yTTGVst6pQWZgvSUgdZ1nTE0m2p9o5TJN1S1vg6NZauSzCXXFGU704eEdFX9YltN6ZzbStIEra1cXCSBqYI/daPnEr5JuqCqAauADmygwTZUktrNNqTfUhtqKglx1WQauhqVZBI4YyATPMo0SiYx6BAEcO/sRayrN7gE9cgMr482RcblZgW8Zte4Z5segelUYkfUstrQXgIJ0Fy2gy6O7dgZe0yGMFmpTjQh6owhBPlh44GK0YrBIOKONQFLHyru1LdosAFGo2YPuntO39Teko0hM5B8hvVVW2jWnPB2QTO8sBDBgAHnsK8bUDPj6C5kdgEIQVCz2cUhankO8azNQ92T@/IILYOh28i/tkXm99jyesheMJGwT@B2gKtoe0PjbhLXjpgBjXYXOG1OrBE3xkEQzjDKc91TVDT/atx8QqsNm3wkyu@6U3vsGNBxMaHpx1DeC2QH9pXlOjYyWTsA1CCxZSyDGeSL2AtiVKsdFfaX83cRcuDYnHc@wtso1lnmGp7BsrbTd7oOWwMAFE1NE4INleO8NzYl0@g5TL6AJqRQZdm2eZVFgZRBV/fAFsqAvWG61NoG0cQYjTRyxtBst82@NbBGRzSK0bexbQr1rh@6BwUQIjixzJEkDMqwucIBjVCV2F0OfzBBjeNJJj3Zq@P9g@ZJ7fx5Rc6OPTfbt1qQw7bZHIBl0Tc9mbEEOzUhtojw8bJ/6jijClVSHDuZ/yQQyId/sd98cfTstHb6DU@G4nnWYNzXMTEOf0bvnMCj6MBLx3UGgRXlCd6uriM3zdg4GXYtROgGho7FKFnEfxP9BzjypRlS1zBYxuGvgacA3EJAHA3TjOFQ6qZSCEmjY4GngNwmlDhCprkt33MHPYPBsYihGkW3KHx5JIH5Jp@7ReSePfaGkZzd5PPkfzXqdFDTBt4F8r7MABowsTh/z6E6vnCg6r2wPBqIjDJcCnT8hST7DVWsPZLDkELYcWSZq8U9XjmKiMoeSuvSQfsodDWhd1dELAGKwWV/PmYHtBT9xEDniJoP4TI3aHXoZwFASXSioALhkB5y5SscEMJ@nANthnlNYGQOEjLglmXr2VN6oGG4iJ64iRsjpmV2xqBOs9Beo/sesMzONkF2Wi1rGSjwBUn3nwvA3HFrEdvAPO3N9YJYjPGjsTvqm23x/M@/34YCmC@enj6lJiRwNIFvJBudpaUlouIL/SwuWYL5MO5bOrGBXPehNHQcgNL7gWMxatR1LJPp6S4U7tQvXBBO/IG6dIecccpdsz9um/5zcSLE4nhfi8e2rQHlCJ5oapDpuCT6TE@Rx6fGuu/obcLCm1TLDEubl4s50buQuWzEBAB19QA6/Q4dC0dSoecyGvNfHDy9r1ytIX4Xc6UUF7JcUW/lzazj6S3LvEMOXP1y3HYyw8suZRpJ21wm7bwSYf8j0@nrl9zZROdiBvAsula3C/0u8VwGBp3skekNwdDIXtPjDlHxFTajVlW/C6fb57/LQPxpo8CxnE9Wn34@RyBJRAyoNchanNbIRNhkzTC2r7em2HPofb5kYYLUEoLiqRipVG4dG8VgGCycQBkOl8fHJpzi7@wsjs3nWgiB4XQ6pnlfbYYWyRro/UyhHXEuVc5@vzZ0LQD9AB0/MFv7ugdCMhJsNq@gWOjnLsHFRsZAcQldd4htSI4/2rlswCyMM7QMp295Q16TxMsyLTk71BCiwRk1@gmj4ts8f9tgpGMDnglciyu6Y4xw0GqJHD1AcfHxIhyRiwiG5izjneFc43ep6dBzrkz@u7gx@7iQqgeooEyfJMMyFkRvG/eJK05/0M9iLl4upGpk9Bf6l9hLx3F7pu2xgpbzO9g45gydbD6AdX50vFymPavveGDJ4@9dvACL3fP472JpjrLN0u0MDSNE3YujLSSKGj5Wo98lhav3u05/c7ub1eFnqQSM3Q5qevF8qIYLNFQ@f6@GCgwhx86L51LVfgn/9wkHDV24OEYZcd7Rri5SZ2Jsa3kGobuAEw@LM3eY26aYWpZ3s5YVgGv0rvWp//wtWo9l3PVbj@GUzGiw8zDCzjY4Ri43rX@b1DbuTq39MB01h3brvkxECveyb4LGpt@5ImWFXP4zY@RzuYdrrE5/bI7NhRrkuPXBxHUcd@iOhxOVE9lYFUMOWWAeDjgEUB9FJ/FBVGN7jm93Khy9b0Elv9eaWahqhmB7D7FffQKOE3TMR@za42GscCO8Ox3bp3dzrjf0a7bTjhGJIZ@rkbbvt5li5rln0neZKX8wcKAr7AzAhrAfUP4CKY3h8N8YYvIJMX@wcLzLvRNviQWTGWC/gj0CpWpdehkcNHuY4iks68MT8M4O9NJsczTF32XcXqRIW47T/5zSAX3attBMA@MTVy3dV0pzto@Y12LhaIWHIx@tzrJxCt7WiA4lcA87z0sL@gSyNKLG4SGlPDdId0erFRmyu69fCS02DQZ5ruG7l9F7ipU7r21rW3cSzM1Tp2X2df6YbG7chW9HW3@IiTT07V4atcWRXj62G47FJ2ZU0HAKzLLaGc/omQOTXu8w@vX2h7HnP5YCTRz8LgjWsjSsuSTe0II6b@NvbBw5YhWNHNv0siPd7ZrYXembOhik3HeZnvVHSxcy92igd83De4UrHI3ARQ80wRRxLh6XKPF5SAOi3aNJeE/QsS/Nqec/F9vLUwPKczy4E9uiem7goOe9FVvLLhwkvsfss3tOz@6ZPZcqR/C2rHqARI74Is67MgH093TvEld5kE4Ku3k9L8rdvtPvP4S7qBO5hnScxeOxB7i8sg1RPwvvVG9BgHjcO3QHTTcxidrwZXWnZ46hhfKckTM0M/S2DLSPgzz8d/EQ89Fx0mNvLdNt8xkuHPHTR1arb7JrC0j44EVn6RYPILX6jo4Lie4w4oEz/vMhQ1KG497XKnR1ZzQc0qM57I89@qGR3Uxn8ZBliR0SoQ@RBWvE5xa5xJpdp2X0rPsKr2XqI9u6zIraL14XS3lcF1PGLZbZR2@tbwGr3KmGMlCJhp/h42hxvbdeiBXYd9oje2PXnd6vG@KzgsEoK58bQMey8Rgx27MgmFp@nED3J4rvmKAQk0NLBYpsabSbM2YOjJP80tGh2GS/YEF/fX10D5cMx7i815xYOl4pJhKRVYYVme4E/9lBjbvJeC7UG3QOlefjrqfeBz9FU2vfGvBF4Ho/XOZyT8xa917JObfsPd2@B6jw4v66RTMlxbsmTfic4CmtUw5WsnlpscAa/CxXLKf1gjXriSPbcE1a1@avc2IJXG03xsIYOa7GCE5R9FRKVSUeCYe5ujaA@VC0ahhXEvIFyR7rW96IYK0Oq9fZ6s2klCvlb1mFySWZNRocK61pO5gMabnvKY9aX9UbldVkJpNcTV7YJZZLEqjZ98zFoHoMrmPRg9MZZp3ZOl/JgG4/p2W@QtLr0SpkUFxtUICvwWymSuC4fJ0fX0x6jvNl/@mv2mJxNhhJHhtYHvQyuzZuKHAGZs@5fsLTFanXhkMdF3cjjusealdMPbNXY941akq@Jtu5Zq8Pz7fFCk@x7QFeTrBKR6jghYoWOy7vGPFC49S0HZOLj0g4iOVnynD644ENTVN71PM0dmbRyo2xG87HgwvB7JGL7XM7zY5Y28RZCVqQQyZp33EuaWkcUvKf/oqva6VlOSBC6PaTp3XtkRRx9U2eFpMahjMGqn0kH03XESAKMhnMojF2@ED4Te6v4mIVWnALkpjxl5tiMnzJ6V7tjGUOWBL3ZeAitrLVUVZrp1@@qecale/YIGv@59/PqjeCb/IXma1NT04zH6R8i3IVDS5CcBiaZPLqRBbZwh0AtOA9ECqxA0hBNxWXv3x0QJsHSO7Ma1o@Sks6bLT6cFU@KBoPjKKRSqh5pamsKmPetcicjVgRN6@Ata6Di283oMU4uBQSo6xO2CfWQ1nJGCxfzMEbZ0gfV98OKs/82eb16JqA7L7ZGtNE2FVBK6xXKDurzcpulVyu2XZwNXz93cWkkMtcTLYOGlnPZ87FxeSLXOFHwD0HrJ7Vx1msQAev9m9WtWru0ydPnzJZvk2W@YoFqOWrNydHJwdn57Xz12fAzVue2cSh4w70UFOgLNAan57Tp20GwBbXMr37tUegQYI3AFcUtqqzXdy5pKpSdCkLgQpWyxl5lTsDEDD/o7Hvib4ovmdGwucBhGbqWExoUXZCgiRkJulFNWjaly0sF6zuYKQFHMH1IAtUIfFIZhXgUga49EAesflc8hJ8Qh5QjPcz6m4ci1AAr0KIeQBkUpAW5peH88wtzPztf4EcD6Fd@11zTDjuzDFC3JVjAAyjUYzD2tGL16cH8UggTuGeMuhiubiLsEN1i@9O4dLliI0Qvmai3oknFjwHutVjV5ZHvReUtw62DH1QLlgdaT7cQ@3Cl0eyWt8DTd5ug2pqTUeo2UCla7RQia9WythMTgCztKChTTNZQlivMr8gHjTXtQFa7D2PvEpwhNmTFuzguTCzP/yzP@e7di5G4P4j4Z7knsHbn4i3Drj/qR@Sz8PbPw/eCvD2U/72LousnN@iwHMTMBEZ@ObohHnUwUIWDfRJJPfYtmHbadlg4lsD4PUVsQ7BebZCzoR4lPob4DwUF7AdlTTqZUrPdBsKLjAvZbNoiuComEarcMwJ717RevNvx7jfCpqS7GZxcyMP/Qszc@UjpDWjXVz2wRGqagmkUrqyhpX3LYPt7u4y2TP0vlnZLHOWZ1f1d@vy@4DQVYCVuNVSZxAHooQxIKwqoimreiqvYlSsnMl8kjXKYJDwEoQ2TSEHgKjobfuLKqHRdASrQDxsczIixT/1rTEwhWxa02fyXXc@ogwg4rhxV9CslIcLOXDdW0TutWgxyG8R7AzBSvIiIau/YxejC7shdocxEJhfLhA5G9x/vGDLWCA9tfm9SsrsTiPMDXt6Zju44OcQqGVKIVtYz@Y31UidkgUqoBdr0CdACXUG6qBhWh@coVfbOzj66vjkbG6vDUEmZ8GSLFndTV1ktHS9ETiSM1LvM/XZYfbs5bNDn5VRqsLxcYQIB8lnyVyU2iylS1J/y1fQzKdNAXMJ5XMPRUydvMwhzSPNYw9DsxHAPT7DP5eqot7c1hu71Qs7MZf8p0X7EBPaGgoXuC482oWYZAt0zpG/Lugc95V7mr8atCCHu2yD9a/8PfRevlsm2KUebpnxVyBJtNY5WOosaUvWJkHetSxPivaLcMJ8ekHX@KTmkdQwQUOam@OIUsNEXuY31IslvQGTjnlHlrYD6jb0YVzL4NAeKWje3aW9a9DhORqFfSTod2HHnrqCU@r2gKoIhhbaFg3N6q6/IjcIOTMHVubcpwcVR7gFRuz96EHe@larrFfqExYsv71rJ4jmDfvWSMFtKRMNu5OQG0XFDOR3cV/HRN3daYgtNMzf6ZKizTInY@DXiTNkYRd@3/Rdp9CLY/tjQA5iYLKvxgOA69Dj1MRWwmSvnAxEBj4mfSLquD1E5EEbtIuQutYzJ22rCy2NoqZBJX2Rz4fbbHTcJ2InQQ9zVn2JC0GijPmsrUERjul1XbPstjlRcNV@qYHcAf/k9durpCrPyQDtTxLbddqzG5V8ZaGPRK0NN/nMKISdnUARxOvOzo7W8yRcHg09EEjxbOS@ACe0oUpnoA@ZMqadXh7TGL0qF4qd9kauyjJVbM@umc1SKeq7wIMCNEYxO@Sy@ji6quAGaSVbgXJGX89u4@OjNWT1vKY1wE2JqGwVRx/2wNzAfrsqgWkKUUqEFhpg@CshRdfQS0OK@HOVkpVorwZALQymitztUQUEXlCuWfVxuPEhUgM5V3d2SqI04upwh4FY7C7QGIB2gZrzbVPgr1jgClxDJQZQe9AptUChPP3atG2orwrIzABqJ9PHIGSumvYP9EiHG78phQQn8blYMQuExjeEHyRv@g7YM6vZMvWAy7fQ7r@/wIa/I5r@afa/z2rZ8o2y2q9Ms2CMqVVltVfJp9bXUqlVe01ZtdEcefwYO863q2DtNDVZkycAlFntq2WQZ7COKqt2eVXfVVbblcIaxYDXVEq9gQjfeVntZlW/za4@BmsiDT4ur53Kqkd7tHKalr8F@rCGrGbTIDM3uFeJzunA5FetVApp0FabSMB32YuzFLUrF2dZ6qOXhZGb7Q58NRK3VYKSmDtehDNQeJcCjV5EjS5mQZs@cHQ7@IKwO63rr3HNCKPxbdPzovIVD3m4YhEKDZWTUDIK3yQHDJwowER8TeuqCsrkN79J5Deh1/dkc11xUk@KuXIqWcyXkwmWeCpn12RXvrnYz1wxM5Osd/Si9m3j5PLk5EfqhcJ2WDKxdyznN@R3bKewlpUS2bXcp61s9v3792AOs3pVq2oNtZ5JNuoK79BtserW1lp6c3st/TTZDHuQW0xVCgUVCu2CFdnFlq6vpTYKT@0yhOzgZ53lwYm/2/DNs2KRHeDn7/6Pv/v53/2M/n5O37@xLGvotdvwdXrskn2Ez2WH4T@5P7Yjbh3drc5HBfoZYH5WqGrkT5LJ4nry7B3uxnyyAn/0D5/gFX9XyEd4E8j8Z0VKVI3Ex0Q@n09M6a@J7vzEz/dkMslM7vxk8/nCBe42X99cecqAq2aKPqXS05B9WXlrW3Yc8ulBCkXmJFj7ONJFn2TwIyX8cw30zrmOf@y8hX@nI/x7c/nmMvPm8tTAv2eX@PeyhX8vPuJfhKrtSpoBUd9VKqk7P2yBn6Y1fRfieL/7vvI7fNhnfiZSArpyiWq1cXubytS1d6lyWfyDEiwHb/jhLqC3cZvJ7L6rplJ1orteFRnYzTSqPDf0qzXf7TZSmdRufXdXa1ark2qm8a5ax1ze4M/kFn8LMtSrizV0Via7pxzjvo8ShZ3hH31e8ETqJy@g63KeLuxmEoXD2l66cPb6WSIPb8XwFQPX8fX0oLZ//BqgT14c1M4Ovjx6c/D6BPy9RrP69GlKA0F4CvRWG3Ug6YtUNVUZjUbNHzfXNGz1dnjjtxPQMPNpLnDxVymxX528zmZ2gegXzR3M4CmllgFmND4xjlZK1BN1JfUk9STXz13l8pf5y5fOcfh/fDyBAGuS@@C4uV6ul29DhWE583VumptOcgPnON8Gpwl/uQE4rVxnsnG8efx0kuvm7Jydz8fQLf8fHDsvjx1A6EC00SQ3Qty5Djy7x8cvAVkHkv8Af1Yul5sAnZPcFfzn@nn6vGvmINMqhOXgLZe7uJDqTH5vgvLT8kktl9Q2k0mrUdwcfntzW9j8tk62WnGnUcd9pw2ZpZPNi3qyUU5kvYuLLNfTcmFDLtPG1NvbZnO/dl5rNrM4xDXZXU09TWWewqdSTe2Kx5NEu1p@clHKoPj5gpjI7j65qK5n0L2ZAu4XwG83m/rMT4gSnisXUlK5fvv2LX7fXl9dcxc5uN/F2yAUf95mwYu70As@CJpdFD/umMxLnKLUi42bW2iuLpLlpGjQFEZ7vOX8xaTQYQUZOw3Kjgo2Q34dLdPNIlOr1c0ieGxuqxklh50KHuVCHg6HF7JGwygarX2sVGquq0@x66RsABJlp1ipXMi627yQ64UGxi1mdjaZ42Z21lVZVd/ld3chDUyioIK3nJzIjptkN7fRP@Xmdlehj4p/qoqeKkgNPauqAgBqEd4mNwrbVXYV9AMvjHdzW0Unwd2Aq66oDfX2lvvBr6LucqxVFRjHwF74r/QP7cj/f/5fvmYemB23CTSEbbZRVJXW1FQ3NpXt1I74q6wAYxV5PbmOFk5ST9brT9fW17Y26k8aa9oafpXdi2pjQWurgt0DFdmvepV8AgsWNZlWPpXzBTmJ7kSibIhd7X2ny9Z3ythAY0QZPuiSkgwKtLobiHDY/qhVLH9GJcrUBlNvb0CseSAYy4qYb7q4mORQwTCVlVuV1ZuEfltOYArsVvbBRe0g/EqyTBOS8o28qrv1fEO@lVdvWrfYq1jLq2RQFjfK5bUN7t7aBnd@TeVj7GD2lQM3hJiebpRRDZUTKL1JYKSauJAqLbML@CC3w2gFTRWLxZVsAR6TLzYPCpM18amuLfhsF7ZTa6mn9bWdHSyPBnl@WpHKON3H5xbljMxrOdveISoSODGBn11z9QSMCvG3tr/GXXn8Hqx4EvSIW8yGHudWjrWdPu5PczqdFe4PXXvWMk3oXZn9vn8OAnQA@@1rq22uSJ4Jn8GJbo5N83o8vjaDz57llfQPH/QhfSadH375kx9@@T/@8Kuf/vCrn/zwq5//@vuf/wS@fwXfn/LnT//dThF/f/39P/9ffviLX4Hn38D3P8L3P/z6@3/5@/xL738L3/8r4ve34huB418JcP3Jr7//2V/@@vt/@gv4/mvx/cXs94c/@/f8//8Wf@j81Q9/9rf4I15@8lMoxH/461/i/8/@@h/@4y/x/3/9N//w1//iH/7k35Ljz7nj//nX/47//v0f/OTv//Gf/v0ffL/k9yd3/n7/AP/v/yv4PJzOh@B5SL4@1@f734qe34UbYSogAyBpf/zDv/xDkNU/42//BN7gn6Uy/JPyYf4IfT@torXDLj5FQT9lwfzJsWzE84/Ypwvc9ZAPISGJf/UpmwNTLpf9FEcaBf3jX3//p38Jvp@eMvDzQf/QRyA0Tgw0IBW@QSb@CMD/QmSQw/3RD7/8/R/@8n/44Zd//sMv/wR1WGZjJ11LZ/J3dxgSAFh8ABwCbj4EDgEf1FVpShzVCluRCvTEH@HJVsg1WZOK66CBfXc@dK9vkLsIv4uw48zzk6cxL457bREwAT6h8JWFxGIaa9KyvD@haE@CDC0AeArB0F5Sk7mLv/gCPs@giyd6epXqNqtIabZdYVX2DAEr8E7h6KR3aF3xrNeKtO9DMLYP/OCdbej@vcdONPevclBWldh3BC3QVDii7yTwFPG/I7QVjDOZSIQN/4W1im78@gH@D71KwmMyEV3@WQ8JMpSm6CAYUN8SKRSQlJTChVRYGil8ptZo3cTa535ShJSlokKXemBnGRPmwNDYhlP@UbwCLhHFSvTyCCmCDdPGIOkbp1SqfJff2JLgSe9jPMUH2mU6/21CR7Rq0E3fRejqTQblQaqeHZxD2PkxyxdyGqvnGjcbW4WN4kaxsL65Wdwq5Dc2dzY2i9vruXxuM1csFPI7Gxs72ztbt1L1R2yisZOT38vcAqJJJpMtIEZWyRe3ytMKxCQvqYqj3BVue0xvMmB2IAUXZPbc4GQ09uBvMlhwj@DDpEcSewRe8MncSvygGaDxGjNAEx9MTI0cHZfFADoeR8YH0eV8cUee4biKO/ukC9Nu8@SkLfb6BH5Oj758fh55nh/U9p5Lm@zZ8av9mUdRABXZi4PD8@B1i4f6UYsBim8OXryYfRUPNMlWWHErndY0DX7wmaYPPbXVdz5IXluu7uSiLG/mCluyDEaXPMVlQqzHwD67yWRuu1bLzG@Cab0hP06AZehZH01cl7EmvcTJ7508X7VoYTrgcjF2G@Je27RKroWHM46Hyz3hgV7odK1ub8RG104A4HneddCDfet3V4Nu61vW0nX8fu4HEjCjn9HdHiOeBvnNhfTnwaXnYOEO8IQlXHw/wpFXq8NykoZiWyjsbBe3d9YL2@ntne2NYn6zWEznC@n81vbWTi6dz@W385vbxZ18entjZ30DagiEFne2pAQIndXJZqG25mWZnpZt4FEgu3imiqP1qlKibXZwOR@bKG2VJdqBx3ibyevbFzkGEWWJCnBSkQsbuORoPc/ysiTrzGCJw8O93OGhLD/DFxw72cvJchtfitu53NYzWTYpZA9qcQEi9fDtYBMHWUB88GWvdniIGD7gS2EbccjyJQ/hL33/ZQvAbHxZX0cETJa/DdDlALnDKdqmWCP@kss925PlMSdvG/4ArsbfNojYA3zBAIx0yEP2IEyWv/QjgTEky6ccTiT13M9vrSbLR/ylVkMUX1HmizxTX@NLjT4QyYU3EFxZ7oKj60LXRZZb4ETxlWUDXMZUB78BuHC7kT3SZXnK84E5keUJQevGpSw3fX9IB@h5/lzvjdpml3@mLn8aEHQEQdZkfHDY@vLLVrfbcqe1gy9PKeirr57rH6Zjt9VtiYitJnwcjAVBl4Pp7MfEoGZT7y8O@hqC7Jmg5rRpEoVN/VugTHy6mNCg@RUGfQVBi8bKBUL4DAC4hZ9nA3g@01s8yP9QED0nrZZcRpHFqtNRSHD1ND3oQC/oqeOUp6foT0hHlVA/OR0llx5vq5nik/G2vLkll9bgKT@R18EJVYPlktB1l5MXsqzWdxpP5K2iXEo@eZJJPs4/YfLWjlySt7ZA9avlW2wVFPWmo0zSk0oOPLLZXazQWAXhGTRJosUobMugNMHbB@A1P6i70HyAqmbwzWQkDB9WBMUyU/DkPVw6TPNgSjK5VUgm1WQZ4q7IQIsghVYXY5Z9imXQGUDxTgGiu@Zo7NosV76dS9m9LHkj3cWJUEqhxORNaN/AG48znP88BVM5XVprFXer/2ju89/9o0Wfxb74kXibvZmXErdSG4/@2NgpS4kb6fbmdrfqJ/k1m071VMZ/fcxYN7UqrSYx58n1@NBjrVLrntb8kZbaHnQD1p0NJ7G6uiolds@r8rp8rDWDcdVqlobqL3AcH8e8tYvm7krqtxp0zWjVp/4sBZCelVwTlwW38bh4Pvi5XcSS6DIvkfotP5CIVAGcUhlHrOQEVh@j74xxIold8AztfpegwVF2ctMZ27QupPQSjRhFL53RAU31Bsjwd6@s/s32eqZK05kKiPAtSYVxTFNNUsJ2hBP46IxHI3MyUsD2KaLto0J5Dc923m2923738vXx6@PDp7nSdmmbmH5xIQQlnU/mk1SMT6Gtsk4PHth/SrBPTjH/nf1VOVEaJtc3kutB4EUlwXkJbqwhSr2eb7D6eqNRB6lsMLVSUQpppPBJvlncTm2U8lv4lqgWtjRPnyYaYnuFsrGlwgsNnRXyibfxz3Xs5YpmeaTE9sv3n2g0ix9/bhXIlc0ytnq7ewv/1dv67u7tLi5UhAf@85/bWx5O/5gN/4Ue4ScGF8KE4b@dZGrNROO7zC7/38WfvWPOBHmzKKuJ95UqyMu75rsm9HF3mFygMk5l@bjZkDFuwKzZ9Gd6a/j3LvRYA4NsLXgzd9c8VqxCnxH8stnshfp7BbBudnY2tzcT0m@AXXcsFYPQYO1ExzRdbzxYtHii5lovdVxYYgcLKMDxcvwRz1h96p9w7xtCDC0hXB2EplDUT1hHES@6GCLuN/WyuJQdfSUJXRZdUsI6JH84ojyiJclsDbci4o4dVbqRHgGusTGiVfDwU5akR7gcG18VHy7NHnsjFbvBOVV69EgoaW@keaMmIsdIwjOTL0u3ErJHb7c9RifM4kQI3@aj4@JmZ8j37PenjEfyqIZwq4526GC6EYLXWIdTAblZY5QiUY6Z48k/4mCtcQdJOTx6cQBxoDPUoWUMIrbstvD8ZcreSkdlQVsDPAAsCE6cInAEBHTgyRttdYB7iQyFIFMsj@EdWg4BUGmWTxMladYREev42oDoiL4Dqs8DxDx1heeArTVFsiIPgh7KBLAQc0dNJjp0t2ukRenh@Xb1hspu/B0LCoayXVYIt1QIXFAY/O4UimgM2uIs2UrIZsKWb6ShaMt85bsSwAmfkFG30tooPSjzohqWpa8VA2wLx1XK3w0ePzbeDeuDRlkdVEb4TKUG0IxfKhYHWRtVBhUQj2HdapRH9VTKalQG6tcKvuORzdjmCwvJU0XeIOd2BWjB5SWemv5YtzPf2Y30Yd1OAcnj9NqPKx/TeiWHtk3aquTT/fS3lbzIB6Q5qnxM2WV9F764JCi2qwAsl5RejnlhlEulX/lY1xtoLPUhYip1CJkBOr16P5VqqJB4HwLnI5b7jx/rqX51Uu5nMipCvVt/clgfgaORquB7SdF3J08@1scQv6TAswLJ9FUgHuIJXt8GtAN9ZeAxL9OQdE4j2XITIG9Qqaz9@Mnaj9cqKysf65PMoJHm7C/lQmlA4idIfDmya0NZ@7HKZlhCc0OK/IVV@kID5SinrVQKmJweRmJyCtd@DCHDVMqn@hb1Jd3o4C83QwkTOw344bR0ciatHqVzgj06inrUxj1XELfmGZYlwPlmuaEFnWodt6Om6ZxmnSAwTFwxg4EXkydPJD9psbgdUkbl0jKZjp1zumDAxYkquq6I77y9T78uUsO@zg16pWdHPz5g0P9d34xUV1JNVOE816gjCKqBm9xtmWssvqUBlA1pD4Ah7YFwGdQiyCShJwRkRQRCafkFBLFQT3T4rnE8eNVD/YT2d1DzQYVwMqAyLyDDSn@okG4CebLAxaxdSg8cUFWkR5AJpAHzYDVYFRQZe/yYidfdCssXtrAtQDCE@5DKI9AcpZD4AygFHEjlB5BR1IeUCND2CENwy04soY3fLSGx406BCKkPab7xTqONd8rY9vh@U@SbysnAsnj06EOqsiEIgn/qvkB8CLv9TUI09yW2d/zy5PX5wenL2hn8QnduO3oUu3/dydwlB0O8vKBl2bTtxNBP8@Y3XxmMKWAbj/AYTLzNqM2@ev2CFQqv9tN4aBWwPsGHM6FBLQWYTI8OCfY0x@1mr61LKxu/Ig0vnqEdLnQhW8Y/sx3Joca5H@6CDTfBejguBo25OGkndjz6wPQ8cXdDxr8Pi845oP3AA9zWCrVQ3PVAi4f99Y@02hanUtO0htu1uhZdctTjCGLx6UzvEY9O9UPCOxra@khHiZZ2tnO5Esul0ZH3HQXfse47NnxH0Xds@o4t37HtO3aEI@9jznPM0EFeX98MnVuhczt07gTOjVzoDDFsFELneujcCJ3F0BmmthGktrlNeFnC5yZVXdPFsPzGth@Gu92hh4SeRUCTn/XcAEILc5AQfWPOE9Lbjntu7eREQkfZYwQqFDbDd9A@PmxF4VSlOR1pnjJ/E57QVkm8L0gCe@C6oJUOJngpDQidWmK4q0@SQO0yo2/qYAyYI7BSKocg/6Za4rvd3Wkp3NmHGCr54B2i44nvECdP9ytx8VkQXFgUzLEVFmLjxwqwgDGRbZGCSE5lKdbScowbMb8o1hVUsMjRJRAFDoFlEN9H6ad57o4XJrl@d5IxhAuTnCOK4y0uioW8UQh5xY9K7T9hq/jpcTvFpNIGM0DcpkcyMFOgeOxB5SZfkn/9/S/@N/br73/2K/bDX/zq//0P/zO6/z3@/O9gs7BCAPDTn@HPv8Kff8FoxpZmosNIBL9ekn/4xS/h9X/6t@yHn/yMB/3pX8rpjQARhKBXGPPn/wR//hB//k85XQwAf/7HHBCjyOlbKWZaKQD1079hDFJDLAGyX/wVY3IKDAxFSF6d1/FGZJM0RxCwoU6uxmw4/8W7SIDHOTUlA17xlg/fUlgAagS5q@P1cGHdA3OGzyuhljZ0o4cbYYWX46H9Y6AJ43haF@Ttug1GjxjuSELu/4CVWDKFMCquCG5jH4d0uMi/yLcchiJsSs4CdXhbg0BFN7UElED3VgL5pp7A1NOw20I90jyXEcHfV3j9pN@AyL5k0cUVkkjLj43jMeISL7rJxO/qotBiM8RPS6ALPCSxUzMfSTCmbmaKDVKZ9YEuY7h/OhqVPMzBEIoEogX8RsbiC3EhPYsuLDlRbQ6OD2cqDH5aYGJeRjVSkFCFyfI9sMhpAa@ixbUeh@f0CoB6rrTeiO3GXgQs/@hHP5KliF8OZchtK4QhkimuMoKgfDyoEAkqRIKAZo6TdE2xUJihgRoO1Ivxkwd4tIiKikcLhQtrjl8OSAb0BfmoabrTH3u9yjxq0shxZTePPIIy36iIenJhk86pMlmdiwA443Eqs2W5GHVuDma@oBbHRG7HfGKltRxTLE6kUhD3pFkuBSWX31lUcvEE70Cdb6QemFAh9zsmlHlgQpvF@xOaLVaMG0O/nL/3qx1fTQQaPkTGK34i1kBh0/gLEL1QHSHFLjkVFbo8NdHlaV07TFlwWxv4Z/1TKmNXtLmRsyuxE/PKGZl8eODp0IEuh4NWcOSO10V3OIsrVbu245pe9JQFi@9DtZN4zofhdG1o1dJ4WqYl7h/EqXp@8lO8XQlaNmGF7vFrYxE1ZxRans2mZVujZhOMz35HDRmIr5qBmwOTEt43C65IfCUwbY@HioOn/o7U@3GSvcujnVvGpXI8FIFJSKTGoENnmH3ofLEe3kTlOZwlmEV@NxVYpK2RQkdz9ZyB0zVtB484wdgz6I9C3EiQPhwSLWmmp5kRoUh0ohUjrasi6tefHZV9XcC71Pz4hTiCGDPSzJ3lMXLWXZBcc2lyPJqf3tnn03sWpffsbno7luuNZmkmTxztwefnJb2uhBgAMCRj/X4y0uJUozlyYqQE3ngLIo/wYBLbpmdA84eU1gC0JsC1DshHOnjzaBugIPzNMv7fXYB@9IOHFh8Zs2dT0DcDurSMumgenf1mG6YC4EeqGq4ZiyQXiPb@A9MSHR3q4aWZTIrLxj2mUDGHQ9P2ggVYPuJ7ZB7XEM3JPS0sqvDABTS5V2l2WVheRPvNttnXp2ZbEZDpCF4/x6em3iZ99bCMo6Ijpefwqy@VXDofM8XoLAACKi0RGT19parLxYqDWIH00GQcUXi0nH80cDermnEQtMLnQBwXNGiCjgujQ9qG0@GUnx/S51duCz3K2x9ekq/wWJV7GQJ84Nff5dNhsupd6vNUCbL0gBYhgNXiWaZduH6z5YA1PleGn8ei@3NKowxBpIpfyjHrZFmJW3eVeEQqfJnkVsnDRPI@oXuwzEVEjSMLVdje5zUhc5j39H7fMJQoRu5zZ4k59pxOQD8sMcde0qo0FyjUICZpuhHeWlTh9oUqWeA8gucVPN/AExFCH7TJBcrPG9q1/pAXhQz0YcRqET51A23RCBfV6DxiBEry3TiQexukaSxN05hL04ilGdSAeJIRIMmIJSlKAYvnriLom53REu2MQdhzh8ddahs@tqO7OPd6k7SSJSvNklfJEijkpJksHSiglJPtZGmfHF6ydEaOy2Tpa3CEdSv5KVnyqwUCuPBKjqfoL1Q4vhvJ0p6i3kp497bnp6slS0GZAswT/kocueXDqy0x6@8Eo6om3muKRmWaocR48HAwW/VGmr45@CdQcQYnBK5UWGGNgLEDEms0Ii0GTweaDY0uclcWNR8lf2hKjG@EYygQnqpEBlVQSsakj5KJZFwZccIwlAYf4QkEot4sLaaI5ed6ZveRI1K38EZZYHY8feKeRvZAW6HwOgBHB3H6YXy/vOIoeAE@jE6MvIzOOXL85IgiXAygLiALmfo@eUemsKxnznPkpR8tofkxAizEjA/CS4nQRnQ62HBom1JiQ2cYFxIKxdk@KxoHP6JSovTORCOtIGrmkmDyFjlDxRCt/Opd2YnEQ9JiKggD67kGr2VBu0C6GINCXRexVHnlAxIiOqdNByyZKLb7wklwXN2kqa1Y1gz5cXmSpLniahIia7iJeayPeOrhvAxubf687qsfE0xwoBERRGIGqXD96nyG/e5w@903qH0mzCSwyLBe3JTOm9d3trIzlPfDZOcLEAPTbF9daBwFKYQsh95BxDK/S9bmTHy84JIb@TzRAPuMte@zLegT3MO32b4Fx4VWgnsV97zEgdnLwnJGzVsk/SvNN1o0TEng4RkPKA2zdjetPOOLihhDsI2Gx2cXsBsv4GjhIT7KgDvDcl7LcSsOzVMEdZuOyQlnLvisg4OrxILTSSOeoO5p/VqwRAs8jpun@8evXnwDje7W1pY6PxWBtRbihu24dOc0QdBtKaTxgDl@FbyDK2nc0cqFLc8vKSMPMAZ0mrfh4ifquCp0WUSfz9RdiMdhIxwVuC7DaqDHtBKaOjo22ZbgK79FRVnTBRLfvAV@p6m3hrNGKB04odNsUvPVbOLinGZTtGJYNME00m8S4n7VQrheQ0rEVzORxeXNneKEAwDjAb@7XQzAifOZ@DoU3It5NPJjB7HG9sjyFzvg@JC4Kp7P5SvreRydOOoEPkQHLspQChvYhS0U8UwIHguhceCTllaKdFa4oYPHlHtDx6aDZunwPjLb8dB0zx96JbLH9rVOy0B4KnSURYQiviDLnxfjF9TbdAA3xMWNdTSE7PMmzcyuRjM@hR3oclxaQ37@aLD0w1MpEhFMa7SAx62@OQCSzkB2F4wmv7SgVHqHVrcLgpQVVwPxBS7nOkTNOJ3Mnn@uVoK90ftW2z/hWawJo9PVxTgwsFOJHYzmscImWFM7aeBs@AXG4jIZhoef5WiRFkHBdwseW9y5nY7EXVGmavyZ9z8q4ltRmliyfJex5eI1QFe6HeGz2HwcGZoWk5akByIzl/5RXJI4k7FC85QarlEbKnJC9s/oQidfNqH3Df/IMAUPqytJj2xSPLgCjBl8bQ0YuDYabTS9pgZLUm32BVsv0I3nkB5ZqZQs4OAzezHsEAZRkVi@uk8oGPmLtvwFTiZKjxKoC7msYXxflNFNZz2HssxWBDo@oYJVmVcB/6UYeVmHrsajBQmvKHIKsKRkVY5hAngx@/GIa975qKAUQT187lJs03VtApOuQJUwutNRLCMu37Gwl1b24vLB2Lpe7ExFF2p2xPo1fhFKWn6NK7BKPBFqOzQ8ghFVd3lWd2fy/nJNeuA6abZGu0Y7sYZGdjFyQMaKZd9FALUoJKGoZ2j51xdeCb5AQ9pHCWyiFQsK8Ua9lzbiCK6jxr3/uUY50qQo@Sg1SGDHA4XSAX6m5S9w1epjiEhNLLR36iKzKVeOxQfivKFNK7nljCZTVLHqGDHFUfDSRP9g7atEC959xXXHodJ6Nr@d29yh9dPMTo/Sg/pOI71mVGRmjizdHnhj97p92XV6V2AssOGH1sSYfvyWseIGw70lhcd8F3R@s5KlY1m2aN/4Dp3ksurvdaeDsy5kxmjTLG6tTzIW7EoqrzCVHLj7hJXk8pyUsrWBL4V8EfWgvtmo2JVceVC3G2U7lVJHqcoolU8p6PE4r5ZB0/Jhl/qoQasis2vspb90EY9cxLFVp8NOHNvoOUmP0W1q0Tk92mvmV6CBPozWpyvodThu1KeD8qQPYhVx3gtbYX0mpuX4cKPp0ETVGKz67ONVlPjzaLy5UZ4Pxxw@eoRLlMvCNo1m4EYajlt9ywAdRPxEEwOXK5ZKYtG9wVBuQUGhn8U9OS3QAikYXPZDDWc4FZEtDtL087IbQVlVsO1S0w@B9KFaIJNNPCDbBTAOwtkbA2eAmpoelVOF7hemHbQzuE9CLeMqcrbih/k7KhAe5Yb2NTTB/KNdEPDYZQKU1hgzVazoJd@6hYsKyFSrJnnQow/jwZDad43TKziCt380h7rlBjE1b4zXviksj8ywfKKxBNBxi7v3rsCwjBaNXxY4sECT25gfxHdCR7gCwYaOt1KBbsTJHcTXdijOI369jAKNIB@44mSIuJQNVRQ1MA4PTUoOkyVG4wxl8KImpxwJ/QChmNclwQMIHuij3pLgHuIee8uCXQjGS2eWBFsQzNecLA53IJxbUksARjiKBuLaHDnNkW71Fb5gGpda33KFrbBUymdsIAKMFwwvj3h8JpaesxVeOlzYYuIF9ZPEigOgSCui8uB7KC0UiocrKFwuImlynrAbdm9iYvAJWNyklEDtYvrqWgw/ixAA9Q9UKZsP9xPnpR1kNCY/GjQ7XSxtYNY6@/TpLsqEIMblL9/wpY@XEI5zRnLIuRXi4XdihOXKI30UkRbHEUvzo9rNt0HDfPiVshCqEF63wnrdscBehKgqWjmhN3YpVfYk9Kl7DVYKtEfIR14t7udjYU56sMdJNTLNWqHTeDhXdZR7iKlDi9wKlQXuw9LLc@z0AuhMHLoK0AE3Z@TMiMmMqKWfm9mH5SYB9FGlJt6UuaI1wDSsCgIXkKfzco3qBI5sNVni/niDhxVHZi1BxvcrNgHBaBdowJbNV@N@m2jZGl/zA3o@V9hI0xA@B7kN2eQrq4fw6b9A5ULGiSZ7jIeax1USW8CaOfAg38iv6myVm8ke1/SLM1fni8aST5JII5uXJ5K6J9BKlliOBRtjyuz2fj3023HmJiy@mL3jKct1hV/oviQ@RARvlzD6XiGLZ6HQYDGOj@lm4@G9TRJt8lzcKIVTF03fxx/W4nV7qQWGVJXj4UgzR@gHgKEcjZUWNlc1VJ1id2tz5Bs36dAKowu3SSrAZC9LUXWO3blDaryjvsHWHOJINARXCqKF6fqUWR3ftgUz2I@nGU0sZs5k5CfU6a7jtBXfYBIGA2HwV0ADUJpvFwrMKm5ehslDcsLoZV2xitpvd8vgsyK8qF0BDzQ@hWwiEWtdqjZlrDYR@8by6KobCsfWCJLyZ3dwMIhrH1aa9UfowAR6tDCSr/FxzxftDBZ6nlrimHqQ93QbB97orCfqWu/K6B8UBMJUoaMd7h@mMrhdMMrA90iL3cM30a6LVbY0tImDQvdHmdRyQM3urozJhAd0/Caxkh17Ll2ZadpXDO@slhLMtPlh5yW8MDCzjQOxeN@f0CY07k2DPCAmUFKYmmab14q4ExB3acuqxPf80aBQXsJjJGhcvm9etcHq5yvih443od8pdBZy2ng4cihEJER7A9kn61O4Xz1Hs7SixyDI2SU8IYyC8zfcd8rHojJ5biDl8YgMNYKijjFJ4coXsozlh4SK8bp6Q/I0Uzd6SATK3ifenYLiIkm@lTy/6HEvG7ICJwfB2eereIc0NodJkHXiTekdso/veXRwHxpCRLkX/RSJBlwxpO84QxRyHGrD@LvAAM74R2fn@wenp5o4DZXPCOAsAh8nxiUYtCFQ3OcphklxNgC3Y/JCeYSZRdw8vUqInPQv8QiTFWzCqnCN7OS8wv2ePAeZPL3NZSOAVzk4sYSmk8Wbh7zMiVXTQ7CjkHdhNCUSLeNH84EjrHh0Lzd0w8CFti/NgQMU79HN3nnOi0chO9CJHPHTTwXpe3VMsxEQz8Mzc@GZWLjGwzlRIZRm9NwQqBQFkhM3Idwtk0Ow9FxaFQaZPnpFu3c0x43QXb4L1tOgk2aFwNWgKLlUBgG7sYBMJOTdgtLnISuxOIGAB@F1Hi7kuyBKPqAyBvs0nj4@JVFAJq1xFUtCZqRUs60@v2M2DCENy3DbCo@O5U1ixyulGBAR6iQDagIv3MRqW62EWFJ5X@NQnZGru09lTQxJPVFmyVD5tZSzFWtBHYlwidJMEeMm1JJAOhS8EkFBOFHQmF9zq37kqYg8jaBFqBU/WcnfiR2v4JC12SpewWHzT/jjV/Y4cT5cYnHgI075hGeez2TFGURKd0VezKa4Nhm5Y5N7ikzd0YqEaU9nMS5WEq8c7IEaPbpX1U/T5PNtHWdst1cCPRFVFL6mmON7ECI4HQLkffFdVoQYeCv9JrsmfakPwCrsmxNWQ5tap4OVpNhkJt6E6uEpkpBBl3nj4bBviX1z7Jqmy3g@84UiTvaEGCNGgyYd4QIcDp9Gl5h8hEgaO0bM17iOIwzw8G5culOR4aVNoFo7FqAcaVLNnvLrHnGbWYFPKZps7PHbkekS6AgRvOR47Qmu0NQkf@KWZ7XD67c9AhMIL353@d3ATqckSb83tozLvS9ZIZfbyufW8xGW@UPVOW19I3q1bxBQyOVzuWJ@Q5L2nOGULx1RDBVxbWQQYZq9wIb@DcimeYWXKkk1aDEI0MPbZ033ymxrknRqtmkMuDUmjqAo4y3LdEoF7aNHH7Ct8DwhvHfUS/PLRUHC8IntMz8bwKCFy2kJ52iHpjuwRnwm17ni10v789IdBy/DpoFonBLm/MBIA3METFlTWZwk2vcvaCHbhbbjAzd0cfej3nKu6JwOwQawUy083ogmWCXcpIoYoonxi@MilEB6Rl@3BihOCwjAXSwhB3wCIGvtsWHeSYNERHwmDf6llm3HoFu7db9ksqD9HKorUN1N1wLtGzKYSoWiRWiHAj5/fnTGzo4Pz9/WTg8YuE9Oj98c7R/ss2ffsPPnB2zv@OQbOjuVPT9@AdrljNVe7YPvq/PTo2evz4/BQ66dQUyZAqTaq2/YwY9OTg/OztjxKTt6efLiCLAB@tPaq/Ojg7M0O3q19@I1NNZfphlgYK@Oz9mLo5dH5wB2fpymVP1oUhiPHR@ylwene8/htfbs6MXR@TeU4uHR@StM7BBSq7GT2un50d7rF7VTdvL69OT47IBhxqT9o7O9F7Wjlwf7GqQPabKDNwevztnZ89qLFzMZPX776uAUiY/l8tkBUFl79uKAUqJ87h@dHuydY4ZC1x4wDwh8kWZnJwd7R@g4@NEBZKd2@k1aID07@L3XAASBbL/2svYlZE5S7uEKlMve69ODl0g0cOLs9bOz86Pz1@cH7Mvj433i9dnB6ZujvYOzMpNeHJ8Rw16fHaQZXuNASQMO4BaEg/vZ67Mj4tvRq3NoM16fnB8dv1KhkN8CY4DKGkTdJwYfv@K5BSYdn36DWJEPVABp9vb5AfifIk@JWzXkwhlwbe88CgYJAhPPo9lkrw6@fHH05cGrvQMMPkY0b4/ODlQosKMzBACcmO7bGiT6mnKN5QR0cScIq@RLbpqKkx0dstr@myOkXECDBJwdCWkhtu09FzyHupyVFk653TmBNz/LJ4ZC7j6EZ@94/wAsPn5wnxz6v4ZGZzs@eRcLg4YmCIRXMQtKbVWzjRe5N/HCZ@yaB9H4DPbA66bxBEwVr924kO44IVBMlFOERKLZfFNrQj/3rNlU0w@JGSPjvhhil/tdUKrIY9/R29TNj40tRRlVfSzO0knzgy2iYy2Pg8EHlWWzbVNEw8UhiNgfJhKHPgGyNmpGWjWi2yySJE0xx8eK6ESy2cEif3rT8eDH/hS@8LYh4gHKma9byGaxD0tk4MlyLKAfEqFD18TJa7QOwOpQkppnmpddJRdNDrv8YoBK9eMQ7Ai6gV1FvSd6y@zORM/MxidicS0PGSv@cTv@MTj8tk18Eyxjolw0l3Km8KE9eqg@NZQQGIUqT4oWConVJ8pjHh33b/OxQrUcHNVCx629rP3o6C125nKFjfKM//PAn9ctXNWHZwdCe1eneA16PG9wAKhgFna/gCXWlE@pZrOROGCVkT0ZAONZQD0Eurba0KZiU90zqVnHE4j4cQzR@NAYu9YkSj2o4S9Pay@fvT48BM2J1G5sF7c2y5I40cgd/SjNn99gOnSMOnIXrOhrC8w0CorUkj2wew7nDiOMnJ6IpYeAeNq3X2jkibeNBjuTuY3Azy/jw0CYXQ9PcLLxEDMZD2FyZX6f7orky@vCmikEQIllVcXc4KXpaOHrYCqRDBh8F3J/SqU2wR/EHVR/v4oHGRICJETMHAxHU5Bc6FyQ3pMP/QWd1LehZVsIosm@HA91fw0SZwzqTFrlimsc6U3IdqQUwa7Fgsb6SsVOMYGIlVkq/EPw6EhLSOLE8fwazD0t8PmRkDdwfiMOX8QgPEqrNjoDNh4GMTP@4Yh8zFlUDIG5Ua1AET1@HKS0y3AgVRVE8fH/@NF80dpApPAFDWwGsb/yKOBzEEKD0E@TKrvhkoqnpiCespBY8Q6Suyg7AkvZP3JGvPsn9DGOKzywj7yugzQkH@QbHyRgZ4xNvxM/CP9/Q54swL8LHU7AHnKL9LBlj80HcpKwcl5B75WYYl37K8Yiy9RCbka9vgnR3EYLphdkTCzDm/CJJWCBKJ2p7/ENP7JVWcAAFHIc14jW3@Ci7p4OPaenVHcf8Zl@1zYGQ8U/8NRvKubwNtJkc6X9JXL4ovIp/ByLJPcCz697SvtoSWdghwu0WGvKvvBkjiOVJ52Dmc6u0aBHUMtJNJENeb@Gh@KUE1XLr/wTscIobGXafugtmKLLD1MNpkPwzMaYwvdnQHwFQmufohkWbIM0q0jownzjSnoa5WeiFceTykEFUrvMzmn5s6d3qM@MTZFYq4yLojFJxPNFW5yJ2TJH19hc9Dl2WqMdYmPKF7RMHBMRY5GBGeErX1UDrlMjex1QT8OUKK8B9a/tSxsvujD5EJcPocVO2IxucdfYS50O2@w/LN9ymHgK2VqNp39k07p1g89X4tAc9dwhFezpf@GFHAGL8xqtS2iHQi7pxiV6yr6MWtcZawIPSisjcu6fGQl9BjoReJHRf7u0Q4CyMrMGlskXdjCIVOINWeUL33xBF6@7gesbdIlx5gpkCogDH1wwK8wgJBntJlykOV/biL7YtgVcfFoCy@n6Wmvp44Fud/SB1Z/SqtMPTs/OevbYG@I90rIsx0cD8aAVXIIOtI9M9tay2861x55BdcCBpLNXr89O4gN/kZGvPT7yxdhXkAZ7RilLc@g7uCfFczojKBqzzKbiPh43HO6hcUIx0kLDWlP0wI0/LgkQpDsILOMvX71mX5q26YI9eEJrLtkLyzBtUB9gTNEqTK/HNQ2CH2LqZyJ1doi2C43slJlp0aBOMLYniQQEtjSKlgJVEQh2xbHVODY/BVGPjAlq8xkO89X2B5V6zlDstsBBUzQ2@RBnZ9xPS3g29tuj8@fYGecdcxqbgWbNH@vDsURuOg34YC1kxtXt0RSYIs0O3gDZ943daIw2WwBGaTk7qVM3wHty2jjs1/cgq3iZktAC1IJAVTWtKzyMl4bhHlJGtM5WDJuFfCuL/atpfjywrzpipSeFpZfGM9m1NCvusHMTZZed9HUDeljsbIzR19fBDnzmeCMEfVljLFfI5/OZ/DoO0b4@q2lUEfDrn9AqSUcvT45Pz4GR4ggiXzCCNhOZT4ei8tVYwI4MHo0KuX@PCtmHB41ZeE/MQxPcPydBLvMZC7kkQ9kbOg73Qg69uDlMQ7I4JO@4dDAr7rYBEYpVR0jVu0bly6dGKKUI9jQdDetfxU1NS0An7ZakCO@Rtj7IVR/nQ99TZPIDBWBOyA9iudQzaItjhaBMBuYgoN4a@a27zgGk2TNlA4bxsVQQjmQ6iVYScE@N4mmbuEbCw9OZBt6V4YJu0a9A5HAJi7/lCGSGdJMa5EZvWX0L6gDQZfQcbHC4uvILgoYgoifOSlTiwVmG2CARLQtOg4La1XYGASinSpKCzXbCf@hNDYclutDNxp6WNzTNNp1ENR7yo5YwXINa3oeWg2/DK4VnMEmJHK2bdEHZ4JF3dMUX7s3HvZQtXuaSnxuQKn/75nkPu/UcEeTobESVFE/EVRb0sNMM53lVKnYdBALjqsiIJRspAcUwjZNSQBWUNwkEuUhc0rjdp0/lPbvPEiPSYY/eMB6AuPisrhkP8NFj3oVzDoALaSUgYGYLp08M34fE3bExsPgL5hfXneKmNIXnETI3VQNmHlp4RDkfG3BY18FfBNZ8jvE5QpPmCOc2hk7wyAPANwuZn4cEqOCAtghkYQHOzEKc64txZgROMVl5ZF/RhjiMRWLBc8FP23BAPyIjwux/6fiql7bt9R0@wRTkvtt3WnguJmgKSA0f03RYsFFv6oHFGB0N5Zs04@d57vpZEqSLvU2@7cJ2oX6YVbbrj1hUL2xeUCKgwusS7Qlj1HZRdSIn/ogaRU45djgoWh0zp4MiedwXdDeilQVK4SOXWFgzcSVOFF6kHI8yiEXJz0QRxMWjtGJRClK4E3ymdDEGqn58xnPm2yW0KolKgFWCAspJA33Cezc52uBHwzR4JHdsx2GhIQQEAesGC/YMInhDCo/AiE3b8zT8V1qCRyu@5VWZjhTNxc@TmvhL90gNEFQsfErHrNiKyJAq2EAvwfEaqk@MyNcuRbEjmirIMA@QYtl2ca@WEk1FLbHEUOezhgjlYcMWTbpOPMBZehn@1pgiEshEieVAeGyBUIXAeDraog5dWV4svh7MSWHLTG8RBQclKHH9TUvGeDOgKLF65WvuACd3zuluQIX@HB2lJPH91R7YddwXW5SIajhDgw@PiRdGnjmB7hnNMRMKan@CEWvhyc@MCLSHIL4eptzwW414LpZCzzYli2AirUrAhbuAfWYHfFoKvLy1IdbhGALqOw4eYd0LHCQWrPOb4KTHWUZWijWizeSOYXENFWdbROnyuOkFCjhe5D5x6ZlcSZGjYkQOZ5sRKdZyxoREibzhNTjsC35QMEekSrFYyP9lBY7LHaMVeylcnsOJYl8mEQEuv9zvEosA2C/3u8SCA0eK/W6x8M@KDlhL8WflIlYSnAW4KFH0GGhMKaqD/IBJFGoyA0UETRvRs2LMvrKA2ohWFWOd0pypFLBIHA0XT4MeE14wCbGROyaOwLx6UBqNMLfQxhmXZjs48ULkPugiVeV4k8BLc/agJ8y0nwKVUUPFK0mCCKCx@SCY6DMP@NpNOjEoyTss1AfFU1G7vfju3hhav1XJqfMGpX86Ukj87kLiM/OnVIVdrNL8/TvB6jJBNS54ctw2QsvSghlf6R6qUhGq4rmLlFCcxUswZR6EKfMATNkIJlGx16G9JGfCxXOAzftQXFzM46DHO@hICRygadsWDmJjP/han96HcwWMrQStqdP5qrIgQmgn34fjySwOOne9F8zGCc@ejqNuH03XmT31bCln47KygKKAqsQ8WWkki7Q29XcFnG8qUd9Wu2z1rKAnkLi/pPk5ESIyLiXuBZNAifipRQGysP7nl/AvHSnWeH3ghMeGYcBalj6zOmjICD7CxLeKBREiiizeDxUBcUbcHTqr/Ki3Onu6BB4ovzSaem9OnvIBn8igUx6yxjVWTOL8LlyonPzWytdvi7pn96afWJj@0BmCjdNZSADBD3Acnw9Kzaj00DSd6Vo/qC1b2J7N5ytqt82c/fbwSv54LusFyDpuTIdKbZvXovW/C7PIi18Cv4UlX/dlZAmRXywkEifadTG4xezxoGW60kOqOo@h4YP3kZZLriQlEqxmQJdZnDxEN0DR8cimSBLNYBQEj42HOF/j8cWdWLlxjMzkAjwLizewE7QmYxI0RjswdVscRSQazK6L8xcBbBqPR8fNXZSCZRvAaM@MDH@@53d@tE0RgiuS72BreXHZo1TTDfGcinSYkiCL25rKNN6n5b5LDJzAqiGo0qyh4ssOToaucctc2EtgmKuLh8AeYj3dZRCBEC9LUnR4Z1DfLaOl5cwcDwNWBkXzAFYuMreCUe4HmFvTh5pb/w04OVugUsQtrAfRwJbuVWqznXy68NY/@Hqw4OiWN@eHh7EDT1pTv1cwMN1iLpfDQ3DmbrfDCQqcJbacbBw6i2Pi2eH1V@6bVhajxu@zW3idHdIAoAiNUxMoJzg1MYb2JnKcFo7n2Lgr54PHIfkJPG1GyzitYHH7m3MSPkKJzDNL7D1mEPP3nvl3UoPhyLsMAou/3gxioxl6JfvL5IA96NHBE3WCJWmEjPrNYtcCTnxUqjfSI3HFI43z4XU86k24DVF@bvb7Tpq9ddx@e0Xmu0PjEQ4PoxFyHASXEvLK49H1EGlmXln9yBUZCIK0OX1T6ztdfscS3p/LRz9pL5NrDnEmTcF27NTsHkyGilx/J4NgQpZTmM0Ukxu4vacrQxMl0xT6/Wj5gWRA9oOgB/pQMYhPs8DQBoq9VKELKFrHSzT56mAcT9mDLONiDiUGovJzYTjP7odGpi4mV/vgWLYCWcdgCbfL0dZvKl7KyRLwgLnyxSTfQR7mOA5BEx6B@LAYt2U8dOq3/@DoNo4c4OZGGuMNtsRGzhuL5sMfjMeaxa5GnQ5ULz4SX/WPGvPRkarM5GmVArJGFKxrfjsGe0ZJdrwkP8AOl9qcTW0jRki90Eiz5HjU2U4Cht8pj5JfA0X1A37isomvM1CtD8d0T0qoz2gYDhdQzOsdjNDECJL0hVH59lqp1WpsdZhKsVrtGTgyGVZ7VmP76PHsGduH92f4/rhSKBbLfOXcvnoDns98z1v2DHBQE4R3su3DK4TRVUvYlcIiXs1WVtPl1WZlt1r2svXas0Y22wXX3//BT/7@H/9ptiZevseXZ/RSfxcAaZqWXTVuVh/flvG9vt9Irrbqq8NGsltGKfv/AA)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
158 [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf),
160 [TinCan](http://joshgit.github.io/),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c)</sup>

### Explanation

The version of Julia that was used for [answer 17](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102433/69655) was 0.4. Since Julia is a fast changing language there are exploitable differences between version 0.4 and 0.5. The specific difference we use involves a difference in the dimensions of taking slices of multidimensional arrays as mentioned towards the end of this [blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2016/10/julia-0.5-highlights).

The Julia code is changed from

```
=#print(17)#
```

to

```
=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )==(2,   )?1_58+4:17   )#
```

We construct the array `[[1] [3]]` which is a 1x2 matrix and then index into the first row and the all columns (this is the `[1,:]`) which creates a 1x2 matrix in Julia 0.4 and a length 2 vector in Julia 0.5. We then use the size function which returns the dimensions of an array as a tuple, this will be `(1,2)` in Julia 0.4 and `(2,)` in Julia 0.5. We compare this to `(2,)` in the head of a ternary operator. Julia 0.5 will evaluate `1_58+4`, which evaluates to `162`. Julia 0.4 will evaluate  the `17`.

The reason for the underscore in the numeric literal (yes, Julia allows that) in the Julia 0.5 branch of the ternary is the need to stop the comma from hitting the `+` in DOBELA. The reason why `+` is used is because using a `6` causes YABALL to loop infinitely.

The Befunge-98 that was previously passing throgh the `27` in the perl6 code now passes through the `z` in `size` which is a no-op.

Comment: Congratulations on 2K!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks. I used my new deleted answer viewing powers to see the history of parts of the polyglot that, well, aren't parts of the polyglot.

Answer (score 9):

## 168. [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), 8714 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yx4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((    (9999999999999999999- 9999999999999998975)/ 256*11+78));;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#( ((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  

Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<

>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=9717
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"--}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \      @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#p>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8eAbIFiF4qOL3VVFDsmqmh4QxUokEkQWgUx0JkACxWLb7kk2t48z6W527mxuV7c9szqZ1kz3Ye0kmd3ZrpnMdF/P9kf0flyTaf7ByN0jIh94kKyZXTuBBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeEU0z6PzmNyn8sCOvO77oegM2sIMBa/nOle0b7NmYPTWdYLW0rCgYq@ZfDHu2OwjKSooVGXNcy2nBOxt4l7brfLR98C8x1ve9C9/ssUHHHDA7sMy@HTBvOOgPB8xrz062zNhez/vg5DBlz3EvINrA9vu@PaDwFcZeu12z12yZEyGrExn2fQgP2K7d/dT7NGCW1@uZbiuAmGuMvfT8wMb4lh0EHiZfZ2y0Z1sTQDcgquk73ovaqy8ngjYZ@xJQNPtde8TMZjDwTWvgeC7SpMBOXr0@OZpIUSyyN6f7@5O@JfZ1znPZ/tC6nAxaZq/9wOyaCfhUB0e@1xpaSJ9Bx4ZkSNO207UDxYKyb7O@qEkDHSzFfNts8WhK2/MZJmG9yy5zmNXvs2bX7BgW6zoQd7@wwWysAvYRwrudgI36PRY4PYASeD07jmPAXNtusaBvW07bsQgDZo8GthsApoHBHCjTtdPtspbdhQQRWlYWgLFhEPPiSBhKy1MYfKz@RCHCt0Ub4ri2JITdhxpCQnhYoUAVSY9r3@z3AUmg5AkgPnB6wH/OIB0w2wwc5HBIEthui2jYD3nfY6YbLyW7cqAGAN@hT7AD28eKMAgu69i@DSDNkPu0a98ZAAmQxDV2ZJs@O/VtW0@2g0SWkJmHOQywIAZV4dZWeu9wPw1VyVMYZn@gpPzl0x99pZjMqLLF8wp8q6paUfZe7bKbxTN0c7aH6u77mqmz6ncsyJ@d2fAdFZv5C/9WAagKUKXL8l5/kDdzfUAwNwAE8yY60ZW7Khn9bixjtjVRFzEG47FaUBvswGVvslQya@j72LQjopqXUOiu514APaGw/tBFerhsrQBVYHnQMrPMvgKqQVOgOvKuicKnHQcqLcAqiTUCLqCIoCCigPcERWW@gdcdUjxIGQyQAYEqkBQhHrTZG9Y2nS4mgXAExbH27WDYHWCaodvCmgcBZLcMJtGwvBZG6nlXkJ0JQMkD2lMv1goJKYgMFeFRUTHoh3/xZ62LC4BTsyzPbwl2fcNankWi1CRkQT4xZFjPNbuEFsTLYu48OWRwZXadljnA7N2xyIKQoFyvvWG3xTzI0L92oGl1zCtoju22bQ1szuRc@mZZz7zkssPhnAsF75lNqFjKgPKmYufY0x2oJctWUsQzud5w0N5guf4eSwf5d9qTsvZk4cwG5HRDX1rM5y8qwHDGEnnBW/ouznlTS0jNYGAGntNS@uNBx3NLLGcx1ap6fdvV0gkY6Wzab6Z1A2WaplecqmW0HbelpbeAF7ch47ResapW3Sk3KhPJ41kCmGsEg83V1ixdVUDkUKO4yvdMxzX6Y/YmJ1yxMC84R5JjsBHzRsJM@l1xjxT1PsiXHjIIyCEj6Np2XysYRR3FBMabWW4MmFXSCRiiwGWnkUmn0pl40QkClDRRUGysp46HYqvb72DHA0Rxgz6Ibx951zKBewKU4gNQAbKsSXxNoh8kC8nEazvt26wJglTyETVJ3uQwfQ4FpYAQNaFkS7ZbsYYMQgDa8iCYksZd7xoyJJyw7wLR4WKm5gVUDSTmBanxgvCcyCdZpEsXBApCa9psI9d0oBFgcwOZLng@VjaIvlzicQAabyQx2dMzxwDF4n1h1GCY04a21APx4I@ZZaPMAeFj8w4FMxlS@wtA6UH1p5Arra4m29hUExv4@VruJyCkP@bvbElY@FpCRYCep21fs67pXgzNC9S7XEhiWpbdHwhBBSUJBiCKJvsb8syJztMIOsri08m8qRMR3WosDxTyvPZEV2iidBGaV64LwpSZQndkLccHsdQdT@YOEa4mMlffY5QEAu/VOShIDQCYzB7Z1nAAUg0Y@LrjWB3gWcTO5XKRd0KT2YNXPHeQ7Ll2mDUiU9x@XFKMfOiFaMwFkcManYYDnSuC2k54UOXHPe6GbAa9GYC9EEXoCGK@Rt40gPfugdnzXG8GUCBkCBajJEN4PYAmdoJaIHRcUu2ixhqqhmEVQZ2B1ICWD/zXGQz6QRn6CWfQGTYN4JT8qT8@GBy6yCz5gT92Bh53N7teE8RyAO0zL3PIW8OmM5ooEPmFdfghUK5AAWsHrAo997dD4Dot3Q5AYJL/DkaOBakkuAkE/1UhIkUygFBaOyBRvA9C5WTsWppqUFMyoNGpWaZiw1V1cGCqkC47Xg@lEHtLigFqes98kFxtkFZC5pPIN2d2daHsJ70unTY@eI6r3aQXFhbS5fQ2SPaFhSfg2kLXE3RlwPWEXDlyYTwDXZQiSy4MrVMK9Gukb@sS8khvYLWNsFf66PQ1s14uLzeyZr0oniV86iDqQLJB7Bw@AE5ar1bRqevq9jUU1Gi2k6XfQel8YvlOXxDhK/PK5O@CCstEBqfX93xUYCvYyd5Nk17Vh14QlFaro/nps3rhrHF2c9bKnN2ms5har5jVJhQK8tN6xoXvDaG71Osr5Vyxoev1Zegkm9V0Ib2kaRu5LmRk6voXG3rG5NTW0jZIbe3sLA1EFfSpWx2f4I2yJV0PSQV4YMcMOqGWNm42IP@m3tAzaUirp7MwxKim00AZC4kQUKGRM4lA@8CAOycvEkO/3iWIR2YFXdQlcj5XJ@A1v8Q9W/QIVaYyOyCV04X@ElCA7rIVDm1cz825Q1KASTv14hnRIAxjkB92HigYnUQcBNx2RqDhQ8MdS00GO2BUZnZgmOd1beMt6RYqA85n2F6NmerMEe8XDCuIKhEUF3D2u6YFLTMJ7kxlZwAQGDWfnx2iV6YAT@o6NCy5r4zQM1imi/RrOaR2D52gg@QF1QjHAn4bqIo6N3TuNlHtgFnQaV8Ape2RM@BKODDCCSZ5bgaajmpfjatNqK1hl49IySE79ceeBQMWG7p@DOWjP7bnXjm@5yKRjT0ADRxbwTqYAD6LvMBGtdpBaXc@fWcBB4pNeRdjtI1DnSSuFVgs73pd78JjSxABWdMwOGMfuBagAErbAMaHLHA@EoFqFx6MXJI8aGN/HaCSV1xbDtVnE2PmKb7xAYQFm13oKMKcMp8c/GQPRHxxtVAA/OVbgT5hIWNQJsuInhaLIohmC03/tDO0FdvqeEw9gw6ytM3yLfsqj81NhZ6oA5peDrQp2yddIkwmpqSUgTcEpaRld52eMziguZmuiz1v1KvI0B1grwjAkWMPFKEuR50xTtNEgtK94PH3RihPA8WmJ3t1uLt3flQ7fV5V88PAz3edJtRfyz7vgd7UtQOVsRQ7tiG1SPDxsnvseYMqVQnOCE1/UhhJxn@xe/7i4Nlx7fgbng2lC5zesGtiZjz@Cb1LNolNJ7V9rxfqiIGg7eIyUtNOTAvigEmErmDoUEwKxvzX0L@HE32GpVxYFst5/DX0FBHXMSJO/hlWv69cZDIYkyYDQ08Rc4NA4oSg4Tel5yZ6hlOBMTU8Dm5W@PxEAvJNsXCLwAN3GPRjJbspFsn/atBuYz8SepfI@zIHYECBDL2XyZtPJSaykmSZCpoZmdfXKQivFx4IqhdOQPO48QpUwh7xTFFlt57ovdUopBQNr1nuava8gBoHRLwEtX/poTYZuc5hDLyKUEIQvcvudMo2yHT6SUSdQmo6hPNwr9mmnxkRymLICQ0SJz6RKl/htBmOij3oYe1rikbKMwEDajmumT@mB6rRs/BJDggSyDTt9hA6nzxoN@i@J1puc4NitptNZ15UoAuiLp8zovnD5iyygTLfmRozsgThB0N/0LVb4vlffq8FFTBdPR1zTB1u6DgHuhFvtOfWlkiKL/Qzu2Ypzodh1zGJDOS6D6Rl4jSd2Q0ds0Gj7GS5XMf0e9ivicoF5sQfaJt38BnH3Le7w5Ytn7MzIRInR6Y8tev0qETwRMWMFO05ySfG1Tw9qTZdz2wRFK6AOHZU27xe7BHvimOdNoi/B@Aph78smm@Gcd5gyH9xivm@enX6@J1NlXKSyQqrZrNo573AbDr2HXzgm5fDlpfrX15QoRG1tXnczhsRjtZy7a55yZ3n6JxNAF5E37m4gFGqeM6Ldt0BBSPog4qSv6bHHawiOwBGvbR5F0y/y3/nRZGrbqFjPp2cLv18DkMSi1jQapC0uPiTi5HJmSBs12yOcZzV@XzOwgypZwXBU7UymcIydmPhpGG0zNTvz0@PfR@l39ycnZqvSBEAy2u3bfu@1gw9ktMzu7lSK@acK5zlLEDkmhGVNN@c1TUDYJKBILN9BdVCP3cxLnYyFrJL5LqDbSN05JzwvOnFKE3fsbyuE/R5SxIv86Tk5MRMBAbXHeknSopv0/RtgXqPHXgudM1u6J41wCm@OXz0AMHFZ9dw/jLGGIY3j3aWd43fuapDx7uy@e/szuzjTKweIIJyXeIMx5qRvGXdx664SEQ/s6l4OROrgdWd6V9mLz3P79huwEpGQU5H4Ay92e3y6b7Tg8P5PB04XS@AkQH@3kULGAEEAf@dzc1xsjmmm6NJl7h7djKBVJ8ZYow6pzLN7oXXXdu4yJvwM7fGh34bJbt4PlSihRKpWLxXIoWKj@cWxXOuKL@E//uYgSZ2fJzBjTnv6EdniS8x8ze/gDA8wGWZ2YXbL2xQSiPPh2nzKsC3OtfmWD5/i95iHnVlb9Efk9oMeh0m2NwAx8DnqvRvk9vK3bm1HiaTpsCu31eIWOVedm2Q0PQ7VaWsVCh@ZopiofBwCdXuDu2hPVNiHDY/2Gj1coeseDhSBVGMRTFlkQfi4YRFGOujGBQ@CGvsv/HtTgFjdh1o5PdqLzPlXR907T6Oo4/AcYSO6YQX7rCfqNwY7Y6H7vHdlOv0Zcv2WgkkMeRzJdLG/TpSQh0PbPrOU933eh4Mfb0e6AzuA@pfAKU5IP6bAEw@EeQPDs6X@XfCLbNwqQf0VdA/oFadyyCHk24PEzyleWN2iry5CaMy1x6M8XcetWcJ0qbndT@ndkCethxUy0DZRFuu@2ppStcRq34smp0IcKaj2Z43L8H7GjGABOrhYHluRR9BkQbUOTyklqcm@e7otWJTfveNI6HHpsmfwLekex6@x9i4i8aGsX4nwlwd9Zp21@SP0drKXfA2jeWHqER9qefSrC/OFPO54WilIjUhgvpjIJbTygVWx@7Z9HqHkm@2PgwD@ZgbaeThd0awkadp0Tnp@g60eRd/E/PQMa1o4Ll2kB@Y/oWNw5MuLg8I33lyVs62ziTuQc@8sPfvZa5o9gFNQmj5LeacPQ9R5qu0FiS7R5LwkZ/nXtrjQD5n68djC@pz2LsT2qx2buEk570N28jPnGS@R@1zO17H7dgdnxpH@DaveQBHDrjJ612FAPw7ZnCJNjAkk6JhXSeIU7frdbsPoS7KRC4hPW/2/OseGp22IOlnwR2bTQgQj3un6qDrJiJRHz6v7XTsIfRQgTfw@naO3uZF7eKkDv@dPaV8cJgO2FvH9lt8/Q9n@MyB0@za7NoBFD4E8XW02RNGza5nopnVHUo8UEY@HzIFZXn@fb3ChekN@n16nPe7w4B@aCY31549RVlm@4ToQ3jBGfCVV86x9oXXtDrOfZXXtM2B61zmResXr7O5PCmLqeAOy@2it9F1gFT@2EAeqMbDT/BxMLvdOy@Ewfqd@sjO0PfH98uG5KpiOKvK1wLQMW/@RawWzQimnh/NC@Qy@h0LEmJxaS5DkS6NenPOLoByUpw7G5QwhRAk6C4vD@6hkuVZl/eqE3PnJ8VCJJLKcmLLpeA/OYlxNxrPhXiDwaH2fHgR6PfFH6Oqtev0uGm82Y2MgO5JWbvgnIMLSUHXu45NNINIMF3xmMl5pRf3tydaDVm9c2GkzIovzmuHB/cDs7pOP@C/LNcuzVQhphcbZ@X4DVbh3ZQ5gZbQfvjgoef5aDcK2kbO8u3AwklwFNRcgHLx5HoXILBzXRZFlnGnsaTl0GMyZA9NHoOssMAHP8cX9tZBuKkhRUYRZAApDeJYCs0yh8iXA883GMXTNDOT0XWFJ8IZvgsXoslYZFaOJqfcYj1gXScYUFynzep1tngzKhfKxVtWZWpZZY0Gh0rGj3ujPtmDH/Ok9UWzUV1M53LpxfSZW2aFNEW1u4E9O6qZiNd26MHxjIrOXJObvKBblrTCTWmDDpmpgwxvQV/wGkYQJA88nxuEcmvjU1wq/M9/2RLW@6AvBqznAOMAIXDHidezO971E56vyL3W75to/Y8wrjvY0WDuuZ0aC66x0@BG@941e71/uiFMgcW@GHg5QukWw4JXKg5e0A5owCuNY9PybM50IuMwlSyU5XWHPRd66dagExjAqGTiM/Qj0wZwYTR34KOq0sqyA9aycUGGLLdIO@963iXZUCIm//kvuQE02W8JuxqZPW18iOWIZlpFsjq2LG8IWEsgH23fE1E0JDI0vyGOfaHJ2NxfR6smsswGTsxJu2TMhtsm79ROWG6PpXHjDlo7Vpy2tlg7/vJNvdCofsd6efu//F5evxF0U7/Iba4FapbJKJVb5Kt48CoER6Fppi6OVFEs3CJCOyJCphJ7xzR0U3VJO@Me7S4hvrOvyc6YrGNclC64bQNkbgD64UAn0LzRVBe1IR9l5U4GbBV3N8HAxQQX349CVltoM4tJFkfsE@sgr@QstCSCN06QLppp96rP5EL7ctwcIr9rN4e0BnhVMkrLVSrO4nl1a5tcvt3ycLtE/d3ZqFTInY3W9xr5QBLn7Gz0RaH0Y6CeBwrg4uM8NqC9V7s3i8Z24dOnwBwzVb1NV7iVB7TyxZujg6O9k9Pa6esToOYtL2xq3/N7ZiQpkBfIMKrjdWkfCpDFd@zgfukRSpDwDaJrGls02RZuedN1JW4VRFEFqdWcusidYRQYCcVT35N8VvrAjoVPRxCSqe0wIUXZETGS4Jl0EJegWclbWC/Y3EFfDSmCNjQzRCHRSGVVoFIOqPRAGrHpUvIafEIeUI33E@puGLNAAK2iGNMRkEhhXlheHs4LN7Pwt/8AJe5Dv/a7lphg3FlijHFXiSFilIxS7NcOXrw@3ksmAnaKNh3CaNPH/adtalt8@xLnLk/slJGSiQZqgbCMD2VrwK6cgAZyyG9t7Bm6IFywOZIpQIDShdvRslo3AEneaoFoao4HKNlApBtk3MUtvHIuU1NALCPsaLNMVTBuUJ3eOQGS69oCKfaeJ16keAQ5UGZs8Tqz8z/8iz/j27rOBuD@Q@EeFZ7B2x@Ltza4/7kMKRbh7V@GbyV4@xl/e5dHUk7vZeGlCYmIBHxzcMQCGmsiiXrmKFZ67Nuw73RcGO04PaD1FZEOo/NiRZSJ4Gj1N0B5qC4gOwpplMuUn@03NNyJUM7nURXBCUKDDJDsER9p0saEb4e4IQ@6kvza6tpKEYZadu5KAiTj4gu0eOEAdb0MXKlcOf3q@6bFtra2mBpYZteurlU4yfOL5rtl9X2I6CLEVbjWUmeQBpJEKSBsWyTTFs1MUcek2DjTxTRrVEAh4TUIfZpGDoiio7cr7VOh0/QEqYA9XHs0IME/ltoYqEIumUfafFumBJQDQBw2bhub5PLIhgVN/mJ8b8SrQX2L0U4wWlmdxWT1d@xscOY2xPZBBgzzyxks54L7j2bsKQy5pza9mU2b3IqGpWFPT1wPbZ32AVumlfKl5XxxTY@1KVWAAnyxBX0CkNBmoA1atvPB6we1nb2Drw6PTqY2ZVHM9GS0NEtvb2XOcka23ggd6Qmul0R9tp8/eflsX5IyjlW0VIAxovWCSTRn5TaJ6Zzc33Ljoem8KWAqo2LhoYBpvJvbpyW1aehRaD4WcYcbN0zlquk3t/XG1vaZm5rK/tOsjaopYwmZC1xnAW1TTbMZMudAmkSd4okEgSEtaEtqtA07tJnl75H3/G1V4fkG0d4qaXylkNl4aDWuGHPMsqDsRp5nRRuLOGISX5A1EtUiohplaClTyz1xbJgoy/RRDMI6OiTSIR/I0n5R04UxjO9YPHZAApoPd2mTIwx4DgbRGAnGXTjHQUPBMQ17QFSEsywth6YATF8aN4chJ3bPyZ1KfFBwRHulxCahDpSt6zQrZrU@YqHl8V1bhoyg33UGGu5fGhk4nITSaDoWoLiFG4BG@tZmQ@y1YnJLVIZ2VR0NgV5HXp9FQ/hdW7qOYRTHdocAHNjAZl8NexCvTY9jG3sJm73ycpAY6JiWSNRxH5Eog9FrrULuRscetZwL6Gk0PQsi6YtiMdqPZeKGIjcNcpiT6ku0gYkT5rP2kMUoZtZNw3Fb9kjDrQ/lBlIH/NPXb6/SujrFA7SRTezrak3uaJPCwhyIVhvtBpsQCJuboSBItp3NTaMTKGgZDiMQyPFk4L8AJ/ShWrtn9pk2pC2BATMYvWpnmpsNBr7OctvYn10zl2UyNHaBBwUYjFK2yeV0caJZwx30Wr4K9Yy@gdvCx0enz@pFw2iAmzLR2SLOPuyAuoHjdl0B1RSSlAksdMDwV0aMrmGUhhjx5yJlq9CmHog1M5ga8kWHGiDQgkrNth9He0hiLZBTdXOzLGojKQ43GbDF1gyJAWBniDmpmwJ9hW0vUA2FGMTagUGpAwLl6de260J71YBnetA6mTkEJvP1rDwKJhudDEA5pDiKz4WxMCCaPDFgL33T9UCfWcxXaARcuYV@//0Zdvxt0fWP8/9t3shXbrTFbnWcB2VM39YWO9ViZnkpk1l0l7RFF9WRx49x4Hy7CNrOuaEa6ggi5Ra7egX4GbSj6qJbWTS3tMVWtbREKeA1k9FvIMF3Qd64WTRv84uPQZvIgo/PW6e2GNBmvoJhFG8BP2whi/ks8MwNbmqjA14w@0Unk0EcjMVzROC7/NlJhvqVs5M8jdErQsnNX/SkGEnqKmFNTB1MwwkovMuhRF9FiS4WhM9l5Ph5ATPC7tSuv0bzGUZT/XYQxPkrGfJwwSIEGgonIWQ0vpsSCDjSgIj4mjV1HYTJb36TKq7BqO/J2rLmZZ6sFiqZ9Gqxkk6x1FM1v6T66s3Zbu6K2bl0vW2uGt82ji6Pjn6sn2lsk6VTO4dqcUV9xzZLS3kllV8qfFrP59@/fw/qMKtvG9tGQ6/n0o26xgd062x7fX0pu7axlH2aPo9GkOtM10olHSrtjK2ys3XTXMqslJ66FQjZxM8yK4ITfzfgW2Srq2wPP3/7f/ztL/725/T3C/r@teM4/aDVgq/XYZfsI3wu2wz/yf2xFXOb6G62P2owzgD1s0pNo3iUTq8up0/e4bbdJwvwR//wCV/xd4F8hDdFmf4sKKltK/UxVSwWU2P6O0d3cRQbPOfoZTTvky8WS2d4LMHy2sJTBlS1QYjip1x@GsLIq@sbqueRRwdyWGVeirUOY7mMcvhRUvLgi1zdbDfYoIZ/7LSJf8cD/Mu9ucS/Ywv/nl3i38sm/h2d4F8/wL8fdejPx7/nLv41v8W/Fx/x79TCP8J@o5plgPx31SpHmgnkJz@zvQ3jXLoQyvut99Xf7cM@5zNSUjDoS21vNzK529u68S5TqYh/EJeV8A0/3AX4Nm5zua1325lMnfCub4sCbOUa27w09Gucv9sCsJmt@taWcb69PdrONd5t17GUN/gzusXfkgot8GwJndXR1jGHuCtBYrNg@EefFzyT@tELGOScZktbuVRpv7aTLZ28fpYqwttq9IqBy/h6vFfbPXwNsY9e7NVO9r48eLP3@gj8g8b59tOnGQNY5ingu92oA0pfZLYz1cFgcP6T8yUD@8dN3k1uhjhMfM5nuPirktrdHr3O57YA6Rfnm1jAY8otB8RofGIcrJKqp@pa5knmSaFbuCoUL4uXL73D6P/wcAQBzqjwwfMLnUKn2IKmxQr268K4MB4Vet5hsQVOG/4KPXA6hfaocFFwC26xOB6tHK4dPk3Am//fO/QGLw89AOlB8sGoMEDohTY8Lw4PXwLQNiDwAf6cQqEwAkxHhSv4L3SL9Hl3XoBi67jDFd4KhbMzpc7U9zYISqOYNgppYy2ddhqra/1vb25La9/WSa9b3WzUcTNzQ2XZ9PlZPd2opPLB2Vmey3S1tKJWaLfz7e35@W7ttHZ@nsfpsNHWYuZpJvcUPtXtzJZ4PEm1titPzso5ZEDJiqn81pOz7eUcutcyQP8S@G3lM5/5iUDCc3vhTElr12/fvsXv2@ura@4iB/c7exuG4s/bPHhxF3rBB6PmZ6VPOkbTTKdp9dXGzS30bWfpSlr0fhqjkwPU4tmo1GYlFUcY2qYOCkZxGdXYtVWmb2@vrYLH2oae0wo4AuFJztR@v3@mGjTnYpDNaLVa831zjOMsbQWAaJur1eqZavrnZ2q91MC0q7nNNeb5uc1lXdX1d8WtLcgDsyjp4K2mR6rnp9nNbfxPu7nd0uij45@uo6cObEPPbV2DCPoqvI1uNLalbWnoB16Y7uZ2G50U7wZcdU1v6Le33A9@NX2LQ93WgXAMlIt/pH/odP7/8//yNQtAR7lNodbsspVVXWuObX1lTdvIbIq/6gIQVlOX08uoDqXNdL3@dGl5aX2l/qSxZCzhV9s6227M6Jp1UJKgJcu2Vy2msGJRmBmVY7VYUtPoTqUqljgroetdsOXNCvbmmFCFD7qUNIMK3d4KWTjqgvRtrH9GNcr0BtNvb4CteSBo1ppYnDo7GxUKMpHOKs3q4k3KvK2kMBd2q8okooVQHlq6QiuY6o26aPr1YkO9VRdvmrc4DFkq6qSBrq5UKksr3L1I6Zi2Of3JsQmPjc31VT3PSqtrS8ViZn1D1wFOcUnnE/qgY1ZC90alYgemVUE5VkkBWpqWhprQU2dKtWlfADJArn68hWdWV1cX8iV4jL5Y2yuNFraW6LO9NPOzUdrILGWe1pc2N7FKG@T5aUGp4PIiX8tUcyoXFGxjkxBJ4UIIX4FYPALlRPwt7S5xVxG/ewuB0mcuDG/XC6zldXEfoNduL4BnxwxY07ZhHGd3u/JoDhhqdlvXTsteUOq9UbtBe62ruXpxbbWRAzb5MGozYg0lsOHTOzLtoW1fD4fXdvjZcQLzwwezT59R@4df/vSHX/73P/zqZz/86qc//OoXv/7@Fz@F71/C92f8@bN/v7mKv7/@/l/@Lz/8@a/A86/h@5/g@x9//f2/@T3@pfe/ge//FfP7G/GNxeNfBWD98a@///lf/Pr7f/6n8P234vunk98f/vV/4P//t/hD569@@Nd/gz/i5ac/g@L@/V/9Ev9//ld//59@if//6//893/1r/7@j/8dOf6MO/6ff/vv@e/f/f5P/@6f/snf/f73c35/eufv9w/w//4fwefheD4EzkPK9bk@3/9W@Pwu1IhyAR4ATvujH/7NHwCv/mv@9s/gDf7DoD8MXxIh/OUPoxeA8D/NSPRHv/7@T/4ifPuDZMREGAD5Qwj780TYH/7wy9/74S/@ux9@@Wc//PKPsZXmVjaztWyuePcQIgURVx8QDyOuPSQeRORRFtiCUqIn/ghPtkCu0ZKyuowjrRz/ZLjnp0XUPtnZJ2UV3jOf8njmCst/EqFnuGGnCKHLKxRaAFW6gKGr@CpDY6jg0vWTpwkNnyOy9Okpg8iQOBaZIj7hiAr/zKeEWMeUFL4QIg7fKLOFMP3CDMI8YU8hGPpQ6ka38BdfwOcZDPvE6K@6vcGqSpZtVNk2e4YRq/BO4eikd@hx8ZjhqrLLnuF4Fb13gUJ8kA6jwvc4Cs9Q9G0elW0rEP4deDzjYAgagvpOAa8M99mF53ci/kghePgvdFh041cGwE@GcT94xV6H4IgfhcfgwUw@4tTEsTbGw3Qj/GcRIAEnowAhMtn48CzMIhN5KeFrZiqXEJ@JsEwUxkTnmQCVYVMA7wpMeCuTCdlMKAKDuaETxZShM3KUoanpJGFQnECZTJJgmDJZqIySQSO5JZHpUmaJbGKWPvcjcKIMZpLjjk@c3ktRyeNwI@wjqIQvT5ChuFHeBFHjOhUtKrDi2koIWFc0OpkL9FM08FC@8crl6nfFlXUFnvQ@xDO/xOlTwKp4kLOxBR@MvX2TwzatbJ/snULY6SErlgoGqxcaNyvrpZXVldXS8tra6nqpuLK2ubK2urFcKBbWCqulUnFzZQUV0ltl@8dsZLCjox/lbgHQKJfLlxAiqxZX1yvjKqQkL2WbFDOuEI5vcqALIgZnpI3eoEUCTs7c0LzdI/gw5ZHCHoEXfHK3Ck7MMrEgdnBYEcsmaDwXKuB8DUUtrm6qpK/ncoFyZrstDlzpxz7KKZ7h@QqAATlc9gJt6QYeO/U8OrnsmW3NibHT4adw7/heEPwOcZ6Z7iUP2nXwQBJrEAY9N3FbctBzBp05MV73e2gHbPv/aBD2ek1AEKc0eYRn8ON3PW9WhHX2@mhOKV@G5sW44kL2xRD9@ODL56ex5@lebee5ssaeHb7anXisikir7MXe/mn4us5DZdLVEMQ3ey9eTL6KB45LFtjqejZrGAb84DNLH3oai@9klKIxX09Q1wqldbWYPR/bMDi5yeVuL5ymXVyDcemK@jgFYyI8Ae6En3E3cFts1Ca231wvrisv0e5ks8gNhp0ALSMByLVLhqlNPDh32J/vCQ/0QqfvXHRAEFx7YYQgCK6vw4mgt3LWJ5z9ecuaponfz/1ADnb8M7jbY8DzIL@pkO50dOU5DPR6eEAc7v0Z4GqH02YFxUApUSptbqxubC6XNrIbmxsrqzCkW80WS9ni@sb6ZiFbLBQ3imsbq5vF7MbK5vIKCCQIXd1cV1LQ6p12Pg9StKiq9HRcC08e2sIjnDyjs62kWnYb2ZSNtJbOUq3QY7jB1OWNswKDhKqCxmxLo6paWkEzv@UiK6qKajKLpfb3dwr7@6r6DF9wDnKnoKotfFndKBTWn6mqTSE7IDRLkKiDb3trOFmpqg6@7NT29xHCB3wpbSAMVb3kIfylK1/WIZqLL8vLCICp6rchuAIA9zhGG5RqwF8KhWc7qjrk6G3AH8Sr8bcVQnYPXzAAE@3zkB0IU9UvZSJQZVX1mMcTWT2X5a3VVPWAv9RqCOIrKvwqL9TX@FKjDyTy4Q04V1UvwHHhwyBeVZvgRP5VVQtc1tgEvx64cLejOzBVdczLgSVR1RHFNq1LVT2X/pAP4PP8udkZtOwL/hn7/GlB0AEEOaPh3n7zyy@bFxdNf1zb@/KYgr766rn5YTz0mxdNkbB5Dh8PU0HQZW88@bEx6Pzc7M4O@hqC3Img8/G5TRiem98CZuJzgRn1zr/CoK8gaNb6lAAInx5EbuLnWQ@ez8wmD5IfCqLnqNlUK8iy2HTaGjGumaUHnUeo3zA0Mwg08wlJqzJKKq@tFbLDDT23@mS4oa6tq@UleKpP1GVwQtNghXSBMTV9pqp6fbPxRF1fVcvpJ09y6cfFJ0xd31TL6vo69Ld65RYFnabftLVRdlQtgEc@v4UNGpsgPEMNQHTTpQ0VxCd4ywi85YdtF/pvkNQMvrmcguH9qsBYZRoei4rm@rT2rKXT66V0Wk9XIO2CCrgIVMiiH4ssMVZBZgDGmyVI7tuDIfRVhcrtVM7@ZTkYmD4aH1AOZaaugVIB3njW7PTnKQwxs@Wl5urW9j@Z@vw3/2TWZ7YvfhSuIq0VldSt0sKThlY2ldSNcntzu7Utc/yajcdmRg7j2GPGLjKLymIaC55eTo5batXaxXFNzlXWdmD0vOyteKnFxUUltXW6rS6rh8Z5uDyxnac1rzNcEMPFI@PsfGsh81utXeSM7adyuQ9Qzyu@jZb4LbzCgy8hbKxiRVywIJX5LT@QiVIFmEoF533VFLYeq@sNce1264wXaOu7FC0xsKOb9tAlU6zyS9QgNbPM@@p6A1j4u1dO92ZjObdNFgQacNjtLXGFdUjLu0rK9YQTCAm6@MAeDTRQOFdJ4YT66p9svlt/t/Hu5evD14f7TwvljfIGUf1MMkq2mC6moR6fQk/lHO@Bmv/JWy1@535VSZX76eWV9HJYb2fVFCcSuJHztXq92GD15UajDtzWYDq8VqulJ8XVjcxKubjO9NQ27pcoraf6QG90FtcLueVUQ8BZWdfBTRPEpWLqbfJznXi5ouVQJbXx8j1OJ8grJ5wSufJ5xhZvt27hf/u2vrV1u4W2v/DAf/5ze8vD6R9LI1/oEX0S8aI4Ufhvx3nGearxXW6L/2/hz84hJ4K6tqrqqffVbeCHd@fvzlNKapOpJarCTF6MDxjj@smSS392sIR/7yKPJVC4lsI3e2spYKvbRRjD2Uv5fP5M/1EJlJfNzbWNtZTyGyDXHdaXEBqaI7Vt0NuHvVn2SDXfeWmirZYb2iSB4@XwI54t/FTeKiL1HIaKDhrcoaYT9xPKT8yLLuNJ@o2DPO4OQV9FQZdDN0axNrEhrrsMyMqfLeFGZ9wEpys3yiOANbQGtLEEfiqK8gh3OOCrJuNl2eNgoOPEUEFXHj0SMjgYGMHgHIFjIuGZK1aUWwXJY7ZaAaPTvXG5kO@cM3G/gNfnJ4J0x4wnCqihcKWNNr1hvjGEl1ibYwGlWWKUI2GOhePZP@LRmsM2orJ/8GIP0sBIs02WQSK16jfx7Hsq3kJbZ2FXAjTAA6CrglIUHSMCOPDkfbLew@15lkYxM6yI4W2yMIJYWVbMEiZZ1hYJ6/jagOQIvg2iLQDAPHeNl4AtnYtsRRkEPlQIICGWjnpEdJj@hZUVtYenZdYbOruRm4A0DGVbrBTtUhKwoDL4fVWU0Oq1xDne1YjMBK3YyELVVvhmEi2MJ3wiQt0qS4Nsr8Krql9RvtYsUB08X6t813v82HrXr/caFb1XHeAzk@lBL32pOTzK0qDaqwJ79OtOozKoZzJOo9rTv9bwHY/Lxy5dKECBLsoGJXergAtabAV69mPdzX3nNrL7dTcDKA@zSz@pfsya1QKqLlmnWsx2s99Wi6IckOeg@jHjVswt@KKVXWKjDigmGbOS8MIkl1q3@rFuNlAX6kLCTGYfCgN4BvVuJtPQIfMuBE4nrHQfPzYz3e1RpZvL6Rjr3fKT/foAHI1MFd/Lmrk1evKxPoT0ZQ2eVcimqwPykE7Q@jbEHfCrAI15nUaocxxJVRsBer1qdeknT5Z@slRdWPhYH@V6jSwnf7kQcQMiP0LkK7GNUNrST3Q2QRJaQdXUL5zyFwYIRzXrZDJA5Gw/lpJjuPQTCOlnMhLrW5SXdIuOtOBEDhObd/jR2XQOLxlk0/nlAV0DMGjhNkZIWwssxxHR@f7TvgODZhM3u2fpjHyTYmCYuNYLA89GT54oMmuxXwRyRuHStJmJg2@63MXHpVy6Io7v679Pvs4Sw1LmhoNOOq8dhrfLa7HmSqKJGlzgW3WMgmLgpnBb4RKL7xICYUPSA@KQ9MB4OZQiSCQhJ0TMqgiE2pIVBKlQTrT5mRS0@x7lE6rXYcsHEcLRgMY8Aw0n@6FKsgn4yQEXc7YoP3BAU1EeQSEQByyD02DbIMjY48dMvG5VWbG0jn0BRsN4HzJFjDSFKWT@AEwBBmL5AXgU5SFlArg9whDcBZfIaOV3y0hsYtUgQeZDlu9lNWgvqzZ0A76FG@mmczSwLh49@pCprgiE4J9GJ5Aewm5/kxLdfZntHL48en26d/yydgK/MFrbiF@DIa@Ymrpgpo8XxzQdl3ZyWeZx0f7mK4sxDXTfAR6qizfItdhXr1@wUunVbhaPxAPSp/jkMHSo5RCSHdCR44Hh@Rf5a@fSySfvq8TLvmjTGN2OmZP3ZSA61Dl3o43l0b7yAGe@oDMX53glrqbo2UEg7s3JyTsI6RQV2mLfw53i0ArFPTtkjy9NismAHQ0GsrQtwncuHLpYrsMBJNLTjQMDnpzah4L347TMgYkcrWxuFAplVsiioygdJelYlo4V6ViVjjXpWJeODenYFI6ihFzkkGH8u7y8FjnXI@dG5NwMnSuFyBlBWClFzuXIuRI5VyNnlNtKmNvaBsFlKUlNarq2j2HFlQ0ZhsdOwAAIPVcBTHHScwUQLU3FhOQrU56Q30bSc32zIDI6yB9ipFJpLXoH6SPjVjWOVZbjkeU58zfhCX2Vwsd6xLB7vg9SaW@EF4IB0@llhhtlFQWP1LC6tgnKgD0ALaW6D/xv62V@gIQ/LkebZRFCtRi@Q3K8jwLSFOlOO84@M4JLs4I5tNJMaPx8DxYSJrbTWCDJsSwneloOcSXhF4e6gAIWKTonRonHwDpIbk2WeZ76w5lZLt@dZQLgzCynkOJwV2elQtpoBLwqk1L/T9CqMj@up9hU26AGiBtMiQcmKhRPEqneFMvqr7//0/@N/fr7n/@K/fDnv/p//@P/iO7/gD//O@gsrBRG@NnPGZk2wM@/YmTIQEYVUSKKv1xWf/jTX8Lr//Dv2A8//TkP@pO/ULMrISAIQa8o5S/@Gf78Af78n2p2NYz4iz/iETGJmr1VEqqVBrF@9teMQW4IJQT2p3/JmJoBBUMTnFfnbbwRO3eAAwjJUCdXYzKc/@I9UEDjgp5RAa54K0ZvGawAPQbcN/FKzqjtgTrDF@1QSlum1cG95cLLC1D/sVCF8QLjAvjtugVKj5itSEPpf5@VWTqDcXQ0sm/hGIdkuCi/KLcahWLcjJoH7PAuGQGKbskKMYHhrQL8TSOBcWDgsIVGpEXOI4K@r/DKX9mBqJKz6NIgReQlU@O0jLhAkW6RkkNdZFrshvgBJHR5kiI2PxdjGSbEzUS1QS6TPjBkjI4kiCclD7vXhyqBZCG9kbD4QlTIToKLak40m73D/YkGg58mqJiXcYkUZlRlqnpPXKS0iK@jxrWcjM/xFRHqhfJyI3HAwazI6o9//GNVifkVkIf8lkYQYoXiIiMMKiaDSrGgUiwIcOYwSdaslkoTOFDHgXIxeZgHTxYTUclkEXNhy5H1gGjAWJDPimbb3WHQqU6DJomcFHbTwGMgi42qaCdnLsmcbabqUwkAZjJNdbIuZ4MuTMWZrqjZKZHaCZ9Ebc2HlEgTaxREPWWSSmHNFTdn1VwywztAFxuZB2ZUKvyOGeUemNHa6v0ZTVYrpk2An0/f@8WOFBOhhI@A8YafSnRQ2DX@KbBeJI4QY5@cmg5DnpoY8jSvPabNuCkT/PPyDNzE9Zh@7GRcHMS88gY2nx542vdgyOGhFhy7jfe1iJ4YdvBrrC9cz7eD@MElDt/a7abx6BzLu3ChV8viWbyOuPsVl@L5EWzJfiXs2YQWusOv6kbQnFCoeZ6fO64zOD8H5bPb1iMC4qth4X7btIJ3fIMrll4LVdvDvubhmeID/X6YpO/yZKeOdakd9kVgGjKpMRjQWXYXBl@sg7cABh4nCRaR3wsIGmlzoNHBfx2v513YroenBmHqCfAHEWxEyOz3CZcsM7PMimEkBtGalTV1kfTrz07Kvi7hPZYyfSkJIEGMLPMnaYyU9Wdkdz43O55M5nfy@fiexPE9uRvftuMHg0mcyRNne/D5eVkvaxEEiBihsXw/GllxUNgUOglUQm@8gZYneDCKLbIMaiGmNYhaE9GNNvBHNnwLaGetQPzNPPrfXYEy@d5Dq4@U2ZMxyJseXRhJQ7SADmF0LVuD6Ae6HpnqxbILWXv3gXmJgQ6N8LJMJcHl4rZtaJj9vu3inYX8IwHfw/NoIzTF92Q4VOWBM3Dyr7LssjS/inbPW3bXHNstTcTMxuDKEh/bZovk1cMKjoKOhJ7Hrx3WCtliQhWj4zUoUnkOy5jZK12fz1Y8ihNyDy3GEYYH8@lHE3eTohknQat8DcTzQYKm6AQ@OvewP@6P@ZE8XTorS8pR3v/wmnyFJxXdSxCgA7@Ws5iNstXvEp/HWlikB/QIYVwjWWTa2C67LQ@08ak6/DwS3V9SmmUIE1VlLSe0k3k17txV4zGukDzJtZKHseR9TPdgnouxGgcWibCdz@tCpiDvmN2uZWlxiNznzhrz3CmZgH5YY547p1c5nyFQw5Qk6QZ4B1qV6xe64oDzAJ5X8HwDTwQIY9BzzlCybKjXyikvCumZ/ZjWInzqFuqiMSrq8XXEWCxFunEi9zbM05qbpzWVp5XIM2wBySxjkRQrkaWoBayeu6qga7cHc6QzBuHIHR53iW34uJ7p49rrTdpJl50sS1@lyyCQ03a6vKeBUE630uVdcgTp8gk5LtPlr8ERta30p3RZNguM4MMrOZ6ivxDh@G6lyzuafqsM8PhRma@RLod1CnGe8FeiyC2fXm2KVX8vnFW18U5pVCqzDDkmgIeHxao3svQtwD9FFcfaQuBClZWWKDIOQBKdRqzH4PlAt2HgreC@Nqv7KMupKTG/Ec2hQHimGptUQS4ZkjxKp9JJYcQRw1CafIQnIIhyszwbI1acGpndh47I3cHbvIHYyfyJegbpAy2NwusQOT6J043Sy/pKguAV@DA8MfE8PKfQkdkRRmgMoM9AC4n6Pn1HobCuJ45I5bUfr6HpOQKsxJyMwmuJwMZkOuhwqJtSZn2vn2QSCsXVPieeBj@iUSL3TiQjqSBa5pxg8hYlQ8EQb/z6XcWJpUPUEiIIA@uFBm9lYb9AshiDIlkX01R54wMUYjKnRWeW2ci2u8JJ8bi4yVJfMa8bkml5liS5kmISEhu41X9oDnju0boMHgDwecNXmRJUcMARAcRShrlw@ep9hv7ucf1dKtSSCBMZzFKsZ3el0@r1nb3sBObdKNvpCsTALNvVZypHYQ4RyWF0ENPM7@K1KRUfr8vlSj7PNIQ@oe1LsoVjgnvoNjm24LBQS/Cvkp6XODF7WZpPqGmNpHtlSKXFwJwEHF7wENOoaHfjygs@q4oxBPtoeHx2BfvJCo5XHsKjAvgTJOet3B@6ZF4VtW06eSpaueCrDh5aiYUH/sY8QdyT/VpoogUeh@fHu4evXnwDne76@ro@vRSBrRbSRv24cucyQThsKWXxzEY8ZppsJzqeP1g4c9VpkzLyAGXApHUbzn6ijetClsXk@UTbhXQ8boyiAtZl1AzMhFRCVcfELtsRdOV3NGlLpgAi1Vugd5ZGa7hqhNyBCzrn59R9nZ@jcc75uejFsGrCZaTfpMRtzaXIXkNJJa2ZSOMKpg5GwwmAYY@2DckJOHHkGbdDSQGcg4FMHaYaugNHGjvg/BBtBpRr@dpyEWcnDtqhD@GBRhlaaQWHsKVVPDmFp8LYOPFJppUinwWu6ODJ/0Hfc@nsZjoPk9R2vIcgkFOvhPbQvTbJDITnQge@xDDiBllyXcxz@aH8AU@L2xRpClnSJsvsC4NWfEqbMOS4dPr8SN/Q9CPQKREhTDZaQONm1@4BSifAuzNmk186UCudfefiAhgpLy4e4wYupyYkzXnt3I48qi7F3phdpyUPTRc2YXRhgZgHBnJqibMGA1ZaA21qMwuUjb5AWDSTYXieYIGMtCgWfNfhsc6dG9lY2gVtrCefRfnREd6Cdo41y7d6Oz5eMnZlujE60@dTfGpaLFqSHIitXMrT7RRxzGmV1ikNtFHra2pKlcfeoZObTZhdS57Cp@H5j2XlkUuCBy3AmMVta0DBdVFpo@U1PTRJddkXbLmk0FUNHk0u82wBBl/ZS0CHMEiKyHLrPiFg1C9a6he4mKg8SqEs5LyG6SUro5uOT494mS0IcHxBBZsybwLyZTX2sgxDjUczMl7Q1AxAyai6moAE8cXqxyMueaeTglAE8fC5pti277sUTbkCUcLoxlhhRly5w7CXLHvRfDBh14uDqbihZlvYr/FrlrLqa7TAKvNMqO8w8FRTFN2VSdmdK0pzTXqgnTRboi257URHo/qYOERjwXHvQoB6FOJQlDNk/vVFUIYv4JCVIIFMZLGgEW30e3EjiqAdNR7MUGhUYl2KVoxjgwi2AxAobaBnVv0CrVYfQ0LqYqG/02epTYVKIj0gF/RdsuRWc4ZKSYXVMUJKguC1if6h7atCBu9ScN1xTruZL24U1jbJfpq52UG2V99sZJesqsrsgWO6vWDoX7cuL7zOFSgLrP@hObLGH79lbHWF4RaT0mO@@by4Vs3T/vJ1OqBhk847WpSnP9ARBmcqY7QlFg@bSDMW7jqqLOCuc/hk8aesVqa4lC31JBdyI@pefa1RdauFSq/uNipuJqMPMtVBppjR0ONxUa@ApOXTLvVBg6wi80vspTRdxFNMcW7Va7Mjz7U6XjpgdFdjfE2PtpLJBtQz@/H2dAWjDs@P@7SRn8xeoiFOe2EvbE6kdDwZbzDu2ygaQ6vPLl50iz@PhmsrlelwLOGjR2iiXBG6abwAN0p/2Ow6FsggoieqGGiuWC4Lo3uLId@CgEI/h3tyXKAH0jC4IkMtrz8WiR0e5VyWZSsGclvDvkvPPiSmjNUEnjzHM@d9iMajcPImojMATV2PzrFC9wvbDfsZ3CehV9CKnC3IMLmjAuMj39C@hnNQ/2gXBDy2mIhKNsZMFxa95Ft30KiAVLXtNA969GHY61P/bnB8BUXwQp3zvun4YUojGOKNXRorIjEciTTWADpucXPeFSiW8aqRdYETC7S4jeVBeEd0KjIgbJl45x3IRlzcQXgtj9I84jc2adAJ8okrjoZIS8XQRVUD4fBYsXQ/XWY0z1ABL@pyKrHQDxCKZZ0T3IPgnjnozAnuIOxhMC/Yh2C8x2lOsAPB3OZkdrgH4VyTmhNhgLNowK7nA@98YDpdjRtMo6n1LRfYGstkJGFDFmC8Ynh9JNMzYXrOFnjtcGZLsBe0T2IrHgFZWhONB98jbqFQPKpC43wRy5PThN2wezMTk09A4nPKCcQu5q8vJeCzGALQ/kCUsulwmTmv7bCgCf4xoNu5wNoGYi2zT5/uwkwwYpL/ig3JfbyGcJ4zVkJOrQgOv2Ymqlee6KNINDuNMM2PSzepg0blkI2yFIkQ3raidt12QF@EpDpqOZE3Dil19iTyqQcNVg6lR0RH3izup2NpintwxEktMsuakdN6OFVN5HtIaUKP3IyEBe7DMitT5AzC2Llk7G2IHVJzgs@sBM@IVvq5hX1YaVKAHzVqok2FC1oLVMNtgeAM9Exer3GZwIEtpsvcHy/FcZLAnDnA@H7FcwAw2AIcsGeTYlz2iY5rcJsfkPOF0kqWpvB5lNuITFJYPYRO/wCNCwknuuwh3hOQFElsBmmmooflRnptTza5ieJxST@7cHVuNJZ@kkYc2TQ/Edc9gV6yzAos3BhTYbf3y6HfjjI3UfUl9J1Amy8rZKVLTnwIC97OIfS9TJYsQqnBEhQf0r3p/Xu7JNrkObtTipYuzqWPnNbibXuuBoZYVZLhiDMHKANAUY6nygqdazsSnWJ36/lAKjfZSAvD63k4V4DKXlHi4hyHc/vUecd9w605RJF4CFoKoobpS8ycttRtQQ2W6QzrHKuZExnpCW36wvNamlSYhMJAEKQFNETK8u1CoVrF1csoe8hOKL3sQlhRy363Aj4Lwov6FfBA5VPwJiKxdEHNpoLNJqbfOAHdHkXh2BtBVnJ1ByeDuPRh5Ul/jB2qQI9mJpISH/d80c5gIeepJ06IB3XHdHHijQ7SoqH1lor@YUVgnG0YaEf7h6kObmfMMvA90mL38E186OJUHAN14rDS5SyTXgmx2dpSMZvo/I3fpBbyw8Cny3lt9wqU6uZYSTHb5fcHlPEOztwGTsTiFZpCmtC8N03yAJtATWFuhmtfa@KaTdylreoK3/NHk0JFBY@JoHn5rn3VAq2fW8T3vWBEv2MYLBSMYX/gUYjIiPYGsk/Op2i/eoFWacWIQaCzRXCiOBqu33DfMZ@LyhW5glTEIzD0GIg6piSBq56pKtYfIirm6@oNJTBs0@ogEsh7n/hwCqqLOPlWCWTV4142JAUuDoKzy614@zQ3h1mQdhKM6R2Kj@9FdHAfmkJEvhfjFIUmXDGk63l9ZHKcasP0W0AATvhHJ6e7e8fHhjjwl68I4CoCnydGEwzaECiuyBXTpLgagNsxeaU8wsIibJ5fNQJO8pdohNkKMmFTuEZyclrhfk9eglyR3qaKEcbXeXQiCS0ni7cAaVkQVtN90KOQdlEyLZYsJ5PJyDFSPLqXGqZloaHtS7vnAcY7eLF2rshp8SgiBzqRIjL/TJh/UMc8GyHyPDw3FZ5LhBs8nCMVxTKsjh9FKscjqambKN4tU6No2am8qgwKffCKdu8Ynh/Du3JX3MCAQZoTRd4Oq5JzZRiwlQjIxULezah9HrKQSBMyeBhe5@GCv0ui5kMsE3GfJvPHpyIqyCYbV2ESMsGlhut0@bXNUQhJWIbbVnhyrG9iO94oxYSIECc5EBN4hy022@1qBCVTlBKH2oy6vfVUNcSU1BNtEg2d3/Q62bBmtJEYlSjPDBFuRD0J5EPBCzEQBBMZjcmWuy0Tj0XicQwsxlqQ2SpyJ3aygUPRJpt4FafNP@GPbOxJ5GS81OzARxzzES88X8lKEoiE7oI6m0xJaTLwhzb3FIW6oxeJ8h5PQpwtJF55OAK1OnRVsczT5uttbW/othZCOREXFFJSTNE9DBGUjiIUJfvOq0IMvFV@k19SvjR7oBV27RGLXWOvJBYz8XLhANqAjQc/smDY73cdsW@OXdNyGS9nsbSKiz0RxJjSYCgHaIDD42fRJRYfIZHBDhHyNdpxRAEBXjdN15QyvAcNRGvbAZADQ6m5Y36DKm4zK/ElRZsNA37hON2rHkOC1xxvPeGttIYiF255Udu8fbsDUIGg4J7Pr9v22mVF@dHQsS53vmSlQmG9WFguxkgmp6oLxvJK/LbsMKBUKBYKq8UVRdnx@mNuOqJZOsJaySHALHuBHf0b4E37Cu8pU2rQY1BEPDsysP0ru2UoyrHdojng5pAogqyMF5fTKRW0jx59QLfC84TwKt8gy@/rBQ7DJ/bP/GwAiwyXswqu0fZtv@cM@Equd8VvbJfr0m0P75eniWhcEub0wEQ9ewBEWdJZEiXa9y9wId2FtuMDNUxxnarZ9K7onA5BBtBTHTzeiBZYFdykihDimfG7GGOYQH5W13R6yE4zEMBdLBEFJAJQtNbQsu/EQSEkPhMHeU9sy7OGePKBKWsmD9LPo7YCzd32HZC@EYGpVihZDHeo4NPnByfs5HD/9G3teI@B@@j48M3B7t4ue/YNO32@x3YOj76hk1HZ88MXIF1OWO3VLvi@Oj0@ePb69BA81NoJpFQpQKm9@obt/fjoeO/khB0es4OXRy8OABqAP669Oj3YO8myg1c7L15DZ/1llgEE9urwlL04eHlwCtFOD7OUq0ymROnY4T57uXe88xxea88OXhycfkM57h@cvsLM9iG3GjuqHZ8e7Lx@UTtmR6@Pjw5P9hgWTNk9ONl5UTt4ubdrQP6QJ9t7s/fqlJ08r714MVHQw7ev9o4R@UQpn@0BlrVnL/YoJyrn7sHx3s4pFihy7QDxAMEXWXZytLdzgI69H@9BcWrH32QF0JO9H72GSBDIdmsva19C4RTtHqpAvey8Pt57iUgDJU5ePzs5PTh9fbrHvjw83CVan@wdvznY2TupMOXF4QkR7PXJXpbhZSeUNcAAakE4uJ@9Pjkguh28OoU@4/XR6cHhKx0q@S0QBrCsQdJdIvDhK15aINLh8TcIFelAFZBlb5/vgf8x0pSoVUMqnADVdk7j0SBDIOJpvJjs1d6XLw6@3Hu1s4fBhwjm7cHJng4VdnCCEQAm5vu2Bpm@plJjPQFe3AnMqkjOzVJ1soN9Vtt9c4CYi9jAAScHgluIbDvPBc2hLeeVmUtudy7gTa/yiamQuw/h2Tnc3QONj5/Mp0b@r6HT2Ugu3iXCoKMJA@FVrIJSX3XespvDi3O8Qx2H5mEyvoLdCy6yeMCljpfTnCl3HCsuFsopQSp1fv6mdg7j3JPzcz37kJQJNO5LIXa53xVLF2XsemaLhvmJuaU4obYfi7N0svxgi/hcy@Nw8kFn@XzLFsnQOAQBy2kicegTAGuhZCSrEdNlsSxpiTk5V0Qnkk1OFsnlTS@AH/dT9ML7hpgHCGdut5DP4xiW0MCT5ViIP2RCh66Jk9fIDsBpU5ZGYNuXF1ohnh0O@cUElS7TUNwBDAMvNP2e5E37YiJ5bjI9IYu2PKSsyON25DE4/AJbfBMkY6JeDJ9KpvGpPXroEhvKCJRCnWdFhkLC@kR7zJPj/m0@V6hXwqNa6Li1l7UfH7zFwVyhtFKZ8H8e@vO2hVZ9eHYg9Hd1Stegx/MGjwANzMHhF5DEGfMl1Xw@lga0MtInw8h4FlAHI107LehTsavu2NSt4wlE/DiGeHrojH1nFMcexPCXx7WXz17v74PkRGxXNlbX1yqKONHIH/w4y5/fYD54qj5RF7ToawfUNAqKtZId0Hv2pw4jjJ2eiLWHEfE0b1lp5IkX@IY7k7mOwM8v49NAWNwAT3By8RAzFQ9h8lV@RfWCIvl1ZssUDKAliqpjaXrmiDR8E1Ql4gGL70LujqnWRviDsMPmL5t4WCDBQILF7F5/MAbOhcEFyT11Xxp00tiGzLYwiqFKPu6b0gaJEwZlJlm5oo0jvQnejtUi6LVY0dheqdopJSCxMImFPASPjrSELI68QLZg7umAz48Fv4HzG3H4IgbhUVq1wQmQcT9MmZOHI/I5Z9EwBOTGdhWq6PHjMKcthhOpukCKz/8nj@aLtwZChRs0sAnA0vIopHMYQpPQT9M6u@GciqemIJyK4FjxDpw7qzgCSkUeOSPe5Ql9jMOKDuwjr@swD0VG@UZGCcmZINPvRA@C/1@RJjPgb8GAE6BH1CI57LhD@4GUJKicVjB6JaI419JiLGamFlEz7vVNBOY2XjGdsGDCDG/EF5aABKJ2xtLjG35kqzaDAMjkOK8Rb794QAI14o4JI6en1HYf8ZV@37V6fU0eeCq7iim4jSzpXFlpIocvOl/CL7BYdi/w/LqntI@WZAYOuECKNcfsi0DlMDJFkjlY6PwSTXqErZxYE8lQlC08YqeCaFqy8Y@EhVHUy7Rk6C2oovMPUw2XQ/DMxoTAlysgUoCQ7VO8wIJskOc2Ijqz3GhJT7P8TPTieBA5iEDql9kpmT8HZpvGzNgVCVtlNIrGLBHOFy1xJmbTHlxjd9Hl0MlGO4LGtC/ITBwzEXORoRohha9uANWpk70OsadpSuTXEPvX7qWLF1nYfIpLxjASJ2zGt7gb7KVJh212H1ZuNco8g2TdTuZ/4JLdusXXK3FqjkbukAuO9L8IIoqAxnmN2iX0QxGVTOsSPVXJo851zhnBg/LKiZLLMyNhzEAnAs9S@m/nDgiQVyZsYJl65oaTSGXekVW/kOoLunjbDV3foEvMM1ehUIAc@KDBrFCDEGXUm9BIc7q1EX6JbQtofFoGzen62miaw57pts2e0x2T1ekHr@PmA3cY9PFqdlVVk7OBeNAKmqAD7gObvXXclncdsGfQHHAi6eTV65Oj5MRfbOZrh898MfYV5MGeUc7KFPg27kkJvPYAqsausLG43ciPpntonlDMtNC01hg9cOOPTwwE@fZCzfjLV6/Zl7Zr@6APHpHNJXvhWLYL4gOUKbLCDDpc0mD0fcz9ROTO9lF3oZmdCrMdmtQJ5/YUkYGAlkXW0qApAsK@OLYa5@bHwOqxOUFjusBRuVpyUqnj9cVuC5w0RWWTT3G2h92sgmdjvz04fY6DcT4wp7kZ6NbkXB/OJXLVqccna6EwvukOxkAUZXLyBtC@b@7GYLTZAiAq88lJg7oe3n/Twmm/bgBFxauphBSgHgSaqu1c4WG8NA33kDoiO1sxbRbRrSL2r2b58cBSdCRqT4lqL4tnshtZtrrJTm3kXXbUNS0YYbGTISZfXgY98JkXDDDqyxpjhVKxWMwVl3GK9vVJzaCGgF95QquiHLw8Ojw@BUKKI4gkY4R9JhKfDkXl1lhAjhwejQqlf48CWcYHiVl6T8RDFVyek6BW@IqFWlah7i0Tp3uhhEFSHaYpWZyS93w6mBV32wALJZoj5Bpco/DlSyOUUwx6lo6GlbfbU9cS4km7JSnBe8StC3zVxfXQ95SY/EAA2CPyg1Q@jQxa4lghqJOe3Quxdwaydzd5BGXyTNmQYHwuFZgjnU2jlgTU0@NwWjbaSAR4OlMvuLJ8kC3mFbAcmrDILUfAMySb9LA0ZtPpOtAGAC@r42GHw8WVrAiagoifOKtQjYdnGWKHRLjMOA0KWlfL64VROVaKEm62E/79YGx5LHUBw2wcaQV9227RSVTDPj9qCcMNaOVd6Dn4NrxydAaTkiqQ3aQPwgaPvAPZN@zi3nzcS9nkda7I0gBXye2bpx0c1nNAUKKTATVSPBFXmzHCzjJc59Wp2k1gCEyrIyHmbKQEEP0sLkoBVlDfxBDkInbJ4nafLtX35D5LTEiHPQb9ZADC4qu6djJAgseyC@dUBM6k1RCBiS2cEhm@D4m7E3NgyRcsL9qd4qY0jZcRCjfWQ2LuO3hEOZ8b8NiFh78Y2ZAU42uENq0RTm0MxWsliwBvMmZxOibECg9oi8UszYCZmwlzeTbMnIApFisP3CvaEIepiC14KfhpGx7IRyREVPwvPSl6adte1@MLTGHpL7peE8/FBEkBueFjnI0qNu5NI7AEoeOhfJNm8jzPLVkkgbrY2yR1F7YF7cPeZltyxmL7zOUVJQKqvC3RnjBGfRc1J3Lij2hR5FQTh4Oi1jFxOiiix31BdiNYVYAUPmqZRS0TLXHi8UXOySS9RJLiRBKBXDJJM5GkpEQ7wSdqF1Og6MdnsmRSLyGrJKoBVg0rqKD0zBEf3RRogx9N0@CR3Ikdh6WGYBCMWLdYuGcQozeU6AiMxLI9z0O@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@aiXxu@pSqaIhVnr5/J7QuE1ijwZPntzC2qsxY8VXuwSoTwypZulgNJUk8B1LuQZByD4CUj0ESDXsZ@ktypnw8B9i@D8TZ2TQMeryDgZSAAZK25eAkNo6Dr83xfTAXQNlKkU2dya3KwgSRnnwfjCeTMOjc9U64Gic8OybOun20fW/y1LO5lE3yygyMQqxS02hlES2S2jTeFfGkqkRjW@Oy2XHCkUDq/prm50SIxGhK3AkXgVLJU4tCYFH7L86hXzZWrcn2wBFPTMOAtqx8ZnMwkBB8holvFQsTxARZchwqApKEuDt0UvjRaHXydAk8UH5uMv3ekjzlEz6xSaciFI1LrATHySFcJJxkbyXl26zh2b35p2bm3/f6oOO0ZyJA8Xs4j88npSZEeqSaTgytH9SXzezPpssV19smzn57eCN/PFX0EhQdN6ZDo3bta9H73wVZlEXWwG@hydclj8xB8ouZSOJCuykmt5g77DVtX3lIU@cpDHzwMdJ8zlWUVIrVLBgyi5OH6AYoOh7ZFlmiGoyMELBhH9drAm7ciY0b58hszsCTcfGGdYptqJgFzdH2bNMVRxGJDvPCx/WLMG4Wj0fHzV2Ug@NaQOjAjk1/vud3frRsEYIWyXeQtTK77pGr6QZ4jkU2ykmgxXVNbZwc03LfOQpOqNVQrPKkoiJ5BxdDl7hmLvQlUMz12VNgD9Ge7lKIgInnZSkGvBOg7@bR8nxiDvshKcOqeQApZ6lb4Sz3A9St8UPVrf8KlJysUCXmFtqD6GDL9wq1yUE@XXgrD77uzTi65c3p/n7iwJPmWI4Kera/WigU8BCcqdvtcIECV4kdL5@Mncc58Xz/@iv/TTOPSZP32c28zg5xgKgYG5cmkE9waWII/U3sOC2cz3FxV86HgMfkJ/C0GJlxOqFx@5tTYj4CicSzy@w9FhDL957JO6dBceRDBgFF2ptBalRDr1RpJgfkQY82nqgTmqQRMBo3i10LuPBR3b5RHokrHmmeD6/j0W@ibYjqc7vb9bLsred3Wwsq3x2aTLC/H09Q4FHQlJA3noCuh8gy@8rpxq7IwCiIm9e1ja53we9Ywvtz@ewn7WXy7T6upGnYjx3bF3ujvqbW36nAmFDkDBYzw9QGbu@5UKGLUmkJ/X6w/EAyQPtBsXtmX7OITpORoQ8Ue6kiF2C0jJdocutgnE/ZgSKjMYeWiKLzc2E4ze6PjUSdja7xwXNcDYqOwQpul6Ot31S9VJI50UPiqmejYhtpWOAwBE54BOLDUtxW8NCp3/6Ds9s4c4CbG2mON9wSGztvLF4OORmPLYtdDdptaF58Jn5bHjUmwZGozBXJSgFJIyrWt78dgj6jpdtBmh9gh6Y2J2PXSiBSLzWyLD0ctDfSAOF3KqMiW6BofkBPNJv4OgfNen9I96RE8oym4dCAYlruYIJzTKAoX1jVb6@1Wq3GFvuZDKvVnoEjl2O1ZzW2ix7PnrFdeH@G74@rpdXVCrec29VvwPOZ9LxlzwAGdUF4J9suvEIYXbWEQyms4sV8dTFbWTyvbm1Xgny99qyRz1@A6@9@/6d/90//JF8TL9/jyzN6qb8LIxmGkV@0bhYf31bwvb7bSC8264v9RvqiglyG4v61H5hdM7ZNzLD@Qe7FlTvnLZ2BRqtXq2mW/vSJu84GkdOPnHiJQZTc7PY7JiVnBGG7mq6lHz8G11Y1/ZO0jid3CH8z9P8I/kxHWU7rxURaWj6unewcHMTvCQrvH22jpokL7qYwTnPcwIFCvU/J1fNcnRkGa@TY@xA9NOg@5xGTKLI0WoxyZL4TSMrSIWYSADUHtZFDg7Rqrl5cW23kUqmUys3UHMKM26eSBRI3jOLmar3gguyPpAUThZG1GCb6olXmtnUEIwMSEeNX@K5VjbfHB5nCQUcT3inObhjdd6vya1zHsev1Ylfr4hkik/euh@fWRjev08XrEqA1cbbBJEBuegfjZaoTtARkWLniHTrw6Wp6L@6/YStyrUbsYfe644suXkdJ2xCCa2jvQHddXJHcdeU5g5gDT9m027iUyNsIUSy2DY5ULRt3l7oWztdDR@t28VharkLJi4hBJwMOQ51BnGzRxl3UWtflxvdeG5w6XhovL1ymesvQcUlUJ7gu0qVDV3h62bKW@qAN9nlMpCq8R4arWAYymxYmD4@mTRj7ukhJS2S4mxSYtV9HG7liQx6PrwvWUzu9Xg/kCWey0BgG9LUeDu5wugGIgykMOssVGt2Yve@672ddyEz2f5Q1z67EbXxBFoTZOWJJk7Lj22lVnZcKT351zYEgc98LAkeYgIjqIvsWvv/WB6hnaYVnJrgmfmX1Up8Kmooy7vLWyVnKHgG/4wwTP80DcodCCm5IRESzSLTp4xZnqYSlK91bjsKsaQ8ci29C4rkvSCnXp4M20JefSDI3I1DLuaGlrGjK4YyJ/Z3CxpKqPIJDdML9viwYWp1QqTWJZtJ4h@Mrz0Pp10MmCWvnLCJSBDHkBAKQJIrAkaZ9BAUfJRi0a184g0SaLN/OLHZu8lLcStJjY39PtoQx6k5QFq1u5J3RoWh4L@gtzZv7II5kGEjKDW63PJv3ZGGwv@BWTmFKXiQ6kmJjmj9CuSTRiWMNLRnIh804m6wh6rawF3ECzse8TiJWZVEt3JkDARcocrmxRHvkCYCQGpM0ydXx5twJaoBYnWgGkTQuJMDHGBiZO95HkqyaIC@vLt7ZTglxyS8S09sZN8H/Y@abqMqmj4e4QuODWMgHoApEZtpNiOFakd4QgpzZAq9tqQKjGHZoZ5A/7IJOzc2/Rc8Sv2w9yjTEYyIrWXRRwznSQfryKLB6Ol6XE0lleaPUjWTqXJqfinAjz0aIcwzXqIWooCEcn7YVBymINI94Vw99rcyNH4WgFeTrrTyzQRx5EFqCyzoTFUGdr9lGoqFtOcr4qMpuZzGMHDNL2S8pIfQONEWJAydYdNaPiBe3r59Bulvl/wM)

### Mornington Crescent

Mornington Crescent is an Esoteric language based on the [London Underground Stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_London_Underground_stations). All statements are in the form of “Take [NameOfLine] Line to [Station], so you have to match the station to the right line, and figure out which lines to take to get to the station you want to go to. It happens to ignore lines that are not in this format, which is what makes it polyglot-able.

The program is generally initialized so that each station contains a string with the name of the station. When you stop at a station, you swap the value you are carrying with value the station has. You start at the Mornington Crescent station with the value “Mornington Crescent”.

Certain stations have [Special Operations](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent) that they perform, and the essence of Mornington Crescent is to navigate the London Underground to efficiently arrive at the destinations required to find perform the operations needed to run your program.

I initially had a route that produced 168 by stopping at Seven Sisters, which gives you the integer value of 7, and then mathing my way to the answer. But after inserting it in the polyglot, I realized that Grass could not handle the letter `v` in Seven Sisters. So I had to take a different approach

It turned out that there was a much more elegant answer waiting at Charing Cross, which will hand you the ascii value of the first letter in the string contained in the station.  So it was just a matter of hitting up a station that started with T, and doubling the value at Upminster. I should also note that Bank and Hammer Smith are special stations in this solution. Deposits to Bank are also deposited to Hammer Smith, while retrieving from Hammer Smith does not cause Hammer Smith to lose its value.

Here is the final code, with annotations to describe the process.

> //Get “Tooting Bec”
>
> Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
>
> //Deposit “Tooting Bec”
>
> Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
>
> //Get 84 (value of “T”)
>
> Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
>
> //Deposit 84 in Hammersmith
>
> Take Northern Line to Bank
>
> //Get 84
>
> Take District Line to Hammersmith
>
> //Deposit 84
>
> Take District Line to Upminster
>
> //Get 84
>
> Take District Line to Hammersmith
>
> //Get 168 (84+84)
>
> Take District Line to Upminster
>
> //Deposit 168
>
> Take District Line to Embankment
>
> //Get 168
>
> Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
>
> //End Program
>
> Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent

### Fission

Fission didn’t like the `N` in Northern Line in the last leg of the trip, because all the `D`’s in the District line are starting points for Fission’s IP, heading in the down direction, and the `N` it led to was an Endline command. So, I moved the first line of Monkeys to just prior to the last line of Mornington Crescent. Embankment had access to the Bakerloo line so I use that instead of District in the second to last line to allow the second tic of the clock before Fission ends.  Everythign else was balancing `p`’s and `s`’s for Alphuck, adjusting alignments for Cubix, and solving Incident’s tokens.

### Test Driver Update

Mornington Crescent had an unusually long execute statement, so I adjusted the alignment of the pass/fail output in the test driver. This might make the output extra wonky on mobile though. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

## 172. Haskell with QuasiQuotes, 8929 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<

>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796lo
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where{ fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B 128;}
>g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>data B=B{u::Integer}
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#   print(171)#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001754 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9081 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNJkiD4OWPvH9wXV1CVjBDJ4ENvUmQmU49KVWWm1JKysqoppjIYDJKRCkawIkiJTKUKM3uH3nks7nZ7ege9PbdT3XN7uAFuPwx294BdzAAH3H5dzI@o@Tg4XP@DPjNzjxcfkrJ7BnuUyPDwh7m5ubm5ubu5e0v3e7/5TQo/7Ni1J13bHbKh6Q9Z27OuTE9jzybsqW7566VVScJYda876pvO0C9LKVZkzHIMqw3vbOhemo71wfTAv8TYwHO7nt5nw54@ZKZv6APTZ@5oOBgNmduZn2yVsf2@@97KYcq@5XQh2tD0Bp45pPA1xl47tt5vtfWpkPWpDAcehPtsz7Q/9j8OmeH2@7rT9iHmBmMvXc83Mb5h@r6LyTcZG@@bxhTQLYiqe5b7ov7q86mgbcY@BxT1gW2Omd7yh55uDC3XQZoU2Omr16fHUymKRfbV2cHBtG@JfZlzHXYwMi6ng1bZa8/XbX0a/hqrj4bu4TDhT3Vz7LntkYF0G/ZMAIe07li26UsG0KTGBqKGNXSwFPNMvc2jSR3XY5iE9S9tZjFjMGAtW@9pBrMtiHtQ2GImVg37AOF2z2fjQZ/5Vh@g@G7fjOPuM8c028wfmIbVsQzCgJnjoen4gKmvMQvKem3ZNmubNiSI0DKyAIyN/JgXR0KT2q7E4GMMpgoRvi2bEMcxA0KYA6g5JISLFQ1UCehx7emDASAJlDwFxIdWH/jSGqZ9Zuq@hZwPSXzTaRMNB2GbcJnuxEvJriyoGcB35BFs3/SwIjSCy3qmZwJIPeRK5dqzhkACJHGdHZu6x84801ST7SORJWTmYg5DLIhGVbizk94/OkhDVfIUmj4YSilv9exHX0g606ps@aIC36osV6T9V3vsZvkc3bw5QHUPPEVXWfU75ufPz034joutfNe7lQCqBFSxWd4dDPN6bgAI5oaAYF5HJ7pyVyVtYMcyZjtTdRFjMB6rDbXBDh32VZZKZow8D5t8RFT9Egptu04X6AmF9UYO0sNhGwWoAsOFFptl5hVQDZoI1ZF7TRQ@61lQaT5WSawRcMFFBAXRBbwnKBrk67v2iOJBSn@IDAhUgaQI8bDDvmId3bIxCYQjKI61Z/oje4hpRk4bax4Ek9nWWICG4bYxUt@9gux0AEoe0J76sVZISEFkqAiXiopBP/yLP2t3uwCnbhiu1xbs@hVruwaJWJ2QBbnFkGFdR7cJLYiXxdx5csjgSrettj7E7J2JyIKQoFyv3ZHdZi5k6F1b0LR6@hU0x07HNIYmZ3IulbOsr19y2WFxzoWC9/UWVCxlQHlTsXPs6S7UkmFKKeKZXH807Gyx3GCfpf38W@VJWXmydG4Ccqqmrizn890KMJy2Ql7wlr6Lc76qJ6SdP9R912pLg8mw5zolljOYbFTdgeko6QSMdDbttdKqhjJNUStW1dA6ltNW0jvAizXIOK1WjKrRsMrNylTyeJYA5hrBYHM1FUOVJRA51Ciu8n3dcrTBhH2VE65YmOtfIMkxWIt5I2Gm/a64R4p6JeRLFxkE5JDm26Y5UApaUUUxgfHmlhsD5pV0CoYocNlqZtKpdCZedIIAJU0UFBvrmeWi2LIHPeyQgCiOPwDx7SHvGjpwj49SfAiqQZa1iK9J9INkIZl4baY9k7VAkAZ8RE2SNzlMn0NBKSBETSjZks12rCGDEIC2PPRnpLHtXkOGhBP2XSA6HMxU70LVQGJekDovCM@JfJJFunRAoCC0lsm2ci0LGgE2N5DpgudjZYPoqyUeB6DxRhKTPX19AlAM3hdGDYZZHWhLfRAP3oQZJsocED4m71AwkxG1Px@UIVSLCrnS@nqyjc00saGXr@d@DEL6Q/7OloSFrydUBOh5OuY1s3WnO9K7qI85kEQ3DHMwFIIKSuIPQRRN9zfkmROdp@b3pOWn03lTJyK61VgeKOR57YmuUEfpIjSynA3ClOlCp2RtywOxZE@mc4cIV1OZy@8wSgKBd/ICFAINAJjMHJvGaAhSDRj4umcZPeBZxM7hcpF3QtPZg1c8d5DsuU6YNSJTrD0uSVo@9EI0FoLIYY3OwoHOFUHVEh5U@XGPuyHrfn8OYDdEETqCmK@W1zXgvXtg9l3HnQMUCBmCxSjJEF4PoImdohYIHVegdlFjDVXDsIqgzkBqQMsH/usNhwO/DP2ENeyNWhpwSv7MmxwOjxxklvzQm1hDl7tbttsCsexD@8wHOeSNUcsaTxWI/MI6fO9LV6CAdXxWhZ772xFwnZLu@CAwyX8XI8eCZBLcBIL/yhCRImlAKKXjkyg@AKFyOnEMRdaoKWnQ6OQsk7Hhyio4MFVIl123j1KIvSHFADW9Zx5Irg5IKyHzSeTrc7u6UPaTXpdOa@9dy1Fu0ktLS@lyugaSfWnpCbh20PUEXRlwPSFXjlwYT0MXpciSC0MblAL9munbRgB5rDax2sbYK32wBoreKJdXm1m9URTPEj5VEHUg2SB2Dh8AJ61Wq@hUVbl2DQXVWp1k6XdROp8anjUQRPhCv9L5u6DCKpHB6g9cDxXYCnayd9OkX/WgFwSl1egpXvq8UThvnt@ctzPnt@ksplYrerUFhYL8lL7W9dwRdJdqY62cKzZVtbEKnWSrmi6kVxRlK2dDRrqqfralZnRObSVtgtRWzs/TQFRBn4bR8wjeOFtS1ZBUgAd2zKATKmntZgvyb6lNNZOGtGo6C0OMajoNlDGQCD4VGjmTCHQADLh7@iIxJOxfgnhkhm@jLpHzuDoBr/kV7tmmR6gyldkhqZwO9JeAAnSX7XBo47hOzhmRAkzaqRvPiAZhGIP8sPNAwWgl4iDgjjUGDR8a7iTQZLADRmVmF4Z5rm1qb0i3kBlwPsP2qs1VZ455v6AZflSJoLiAc2DrBrTMJLhzmZ0DQGDUfH5@iFqZATyt69Cw5L4yQs9g6A7Sr22R2j2y/B6SF1QjHAt4HaAq6tzQuZtEtUNmQKfdBUqbY2vIlXBghFNM8lz3FRXVvjpXm1Bbwy4fkQqG7NQfuwYMWEzo@jGUj/7YvnNlea6DRNb2ATRwbAXrYAr4PPICG9Xrh6W9xfSdBxwoNuNdjNE2DnWauIZvsLzj2m7XZSsQAVlT0zhjHzoGoABK2xDGh8y3PhCB6l0XRi5JHjSxv/ZRySturIbqs44x8xRfew/Cgs0vdBRhQZlPD3@8DyK@uF4oAP7BW4E@YSFjUKbLiJ4GiyKIZgtN/6w3MiXT6LlMPocOslRj@bZ5lcfmJkNP1ANNLwfalOmRLhEmE1NV0tAdgVLSNm2rbw0PaW7GdrDnjXqVIHQX2CsCcGyZQ0moy1FnjNM0kaB0ujz@/hjlqS@Z9GSvjvb2L47rZ8@rcn7ke3nbakH9tc2LPuhNtunLjKXYiQmpRYIPl/aJ6w6rVCU4IzT7SWGkIP6LvYsXh89O6iff8GwonW/1R7aOmfH4p/QesElsOqnjuf1QR/QFbZdXkZpmYroQB0widA1DR2KyMOa/gf59nADUDKlrGCzn8tfQU0TcxIg4KagZg4HUzWQwJk0Shp4i5haBxIlCzWsFntvoGU4RxtTwOLh54YsTCcg3xcItAvedkT@IleymWCT/q2Gng/1I6F0i78scgAEFMvReJW8@xZjIKiDLTNDcyCG8NYLHpybnwpsJmhuZ1/8ZCMMXLgi@F5ZP88VxhpDCHvZckgM1IaENyFFIKRqus9zV/HkGOQ6IeBO46dJF7TRyXcCYeh2hhCD6l/Zsyg70EfSTiDqD1GwIbxP9Vod@5kQoiyEsNHCcSEWqfIHTcDjKdqHHNq8pGinjBAyoZTl6/oQeqJbPwyc5wEgg0zI7I@jM8qAtofueaLntLYrZabWsRVGBLoh68JwTzRu15pENBge9mTEoSxB@OPKGttkWz//6e22ogNnq6ekT6sBDxwXQjXijs7C2RFJ8oZ/5NUtx3o9sSycykOs@kIaO0366HTrmg0ZZzHK5nu71sZ8UlQvMiT/Q1u/gM465Z9qjthk852dCJE6OdHlqx@pTieCJih4p7guST43TeXpSlWxXbxMUrtBYZlTbvF7MMe/aY0oAiNMH4BkMp1k0fw3jxuGI/@KU9X31ag3wO58q5SSTFdb1VtHMu77essw7@MDTL0dtNze47FKhEbWNRdzOGxGO/nIdW7/kzgt0zicAL6Jndbsw6hXPRdGue6Cw@ANQefLX9LiDVYIOhVGvr98F07P576Iowepe6FhMJ8umn09hSGIRA1oNkhYXk3IxMllThLX11gTHbb1P5yzMkHpqEDxVI5MprGI3Fk5CRstWg8Hi9Nj3Ufrt7fmp@QoXATDcTsc072vN0CNZfd3Oldox50LhHMwqRK45UUmTzhm27gOTDAWZzSuoFvq5i3GxkzGQXSLXHWwboRPMMS@arozSDCzDtS1/wFuSeFkkJacneiIwuI5JP1FSfJulbxuGC9iB50LX/IbuGkOcMlzARw8QXHy2DudDY4yhuYtoZ7jX@F2oOvTcK5P/zu/MPszF6gEiKGcTZ1jGnORt4z52xUUn@plPxcu5WA0Ne65/mb10Xa9nOj4raYVgegNn/HXb5tOHZ4dHi3nat2zXh5EG/t5FCxhR@D7/nc/NcbJZupOjSZy4e34ygdSAaWLMu6Aydbvr2htb3bwOPwtrfOR1ULKL50MlWiiRisV7JVKo@LhOUTwXivJL@L@PGWiiyMMZ4Zjzjn50nvgSM4mLCwjDA1zmmV@4g8IWpdTyfNi3qAI8o3etT4Lnb9FbLKJu0FsMJqQ2g16HCba3wDH0uCr92@S2dndu7YfJpBmwm/cVIla5l7YJEpp@Z6qUlQrFT0xRLBQeLqE69sgcmXMlxlHrvYnWNXfIiocjVRDFWBZTIHkgHk6AhLE@iEHhg7DG/hvf7hQwum1BI79Xe5kr7wagaw9wHH0MjmN0zCbsOqNBonJjtDsZOSd3U643CFq2204giSGfKpG27teREuq4b9J3keq@33dh6Ov2QWdwHlD/AijNKfHfBGDyiSC/t3D@zbsTbpmFS0egr4L@AbVqXfo5nMR7mOApLRqzU@TtbRiVOeZwgr@LqD1PkLZc1/6U2gF52rZQLQNlE23D7qulGV1HrCKyaHbCx5mOVmfRvATva8QAEqiHg@WFFX0MRRpS5/CQWp6ZNLyj14pNId43joQemyZ/fM8I3IvwPcHGXdS2tM07EebqqNsybZ0/xhtrd8Hb1lYfohINAj2XZpFx5pnPNUcrH6kpETSYALGsds43embfpNc7lHy9/X7kB4@FkcYufucEa3maZl2QbmBBm3fwNzGvHdOKhq5j@vmh7nVNHJ7YuNwgfBfJ2WD2di5xD/t61zy4l7mi2Qc0MaHlvJhz/jxEma/6GpDsHknCR36uc2lO/OA5Xz@eGFCfo/6d0Oa1cwMnOe9t2Fp@7qT1PWqf03N7Ts/sedQ4wrdFzQM4cshNa@8qBODf0/1LtKkhmRQN63p@nLq2a9sPoS7KRC4hXXf@/Os@GrG2IeknwZ3oLQgQj3un6qDrJiJRH76o7fTMEfRQvjt0B2aO3hZFtXFSh//On1I@PEr77I1lem2@nogzfPrQatkmu7YAhfd@fF1u/oRRy3Z1NNu6Q4kHygTPh0xBGa53X6/Q1d3hYECPi4E98umHZnJznflTlGV2QIg@hBesIV/J5Rxrdt2W0bPuq7yWqQ8d6zIvWr94nc/lSVlMBbdYbg@9NdsCUnkTDXmgGg8/xcfh/HZvvRCG8XfqI7sjz5vcLxuSq5ThrCpfC0DHovkXsfo0J5h6fjRXCJbl71iQEItVCxmKdGnUm3NmAZST4sLZoIRphSCBvbo6vIdKhmtc3qtOLJyfFAubSCrDii2/gv/0JMbdaDwX4g0Gh8rzUddX74s/QVVrz@pzU3vdjoyK7klZ73LOwYUk33avYxPNIBJ0Rzzmcl7pxf3tiVZD1u9cGCmz4ouL@tHh/cAM2xr4/JflOqW5KsTs4uW8HL/BKrybMqfQEjoPHzz0XQ/tUEHbyBme6Rs4CY6CmgtQLp4ctwsCO2ezKHIQd25ZZhdO56kxyc4w9/Urs6ujWcsLCy1cbH9e/1jvmo7OSqA4lj6pq819/aOR7ls/GrlDcxYwX8I9IWP@0OzTz4pdCOBnecLm3A83dqTIMISMQAOjQJZC09QRtqWh62mM4imKnsmoqsQT4axk14FoQSwyrUezW2617zPb8ocU1@qwRoMt34zLhXLxllWZXJZZs8mhkgHo/nhANvEnPGljWW9Wl9O5XHo5fe6UWSFNUU3bN@dH1RPxOhY9OJ5R0Zmjc7MfdAclrXBzYr9HpvrQ77Sh/3oNox6SYa7HjWK5xfUZLm/@l79six0MoOP6rG8BswMhcNeN2zd77vUTnq/IvT4Y6LgDAmFc97BzxNxzu3XmX2NHxzcuuNfs9cHZljCHFnuD4OUYJXIMC16pOOBCW6ghrzSOTds1OReJjMNUQaEM1x71HdAs2sOer0HjIjOnkReZd4ALozlDD9WrdpYdsraJi0hkvUYjCtt1L8mOFDH5L3/JjcDJhk3YFgXZ0@aPWI5oqlYky2vDcEeAdQDkg@m5IoqCRIZmNsLxOrQBk/uraNlF1unAibnANhuz4fbZu/VTlttnady8hBafFaujLNdPPv@qUWhWv2P9vPlffy@v3gi6yZ/ltjd8OcuCKJVb5Kt48DoER6FpJi@PZVEs3CZDu0JCphL76hR0U3UFttZ92mFDfGdek601WQg5KEVw6wr0Ez7otEOVQPNGU11WRnxkmDsdsnXc4QWDLR1cfE8OWa6h3TAmWR6zj6yHvJIz0JoK3jhBbDRV71efBcYBq3ETjvye2RrRuuVVSSutVqk4yxfVnRq5PLPt4paRxtvzcamQOx9v7jfzfkCc8/PxZ4XS10A9F5TW5cd5bED7r/ZulrVa4eNHX58wWb5NV7hlCrTy5Zvjw@P907P62etToOYtL2zqwPX6eiQpkBfIOKzn2rQXB8jiWaZ/v/QIJUj4BtEVhS3rbAe3A6qqFLeMoqiC1HJOXubOMAqM3uKp70k@L71vxsJnIwjJ1LGYkKLsmBhJ8Ezaj0vQbMBbWC/Y3EHHDimCdj9zRCHRSGZVoFIOqPRAGrHZUvIafEIeUI33E@puGPNAAK2iGLMRkEhhXlheHs4LN7fwt/8AJR5Av/a7lphg3FlijHFXiSFilIxSHNQPX7w@2U8mAnaKNl7CCNnDvbkdalt8CxfnLlfsFgokEw0ufbE7IJStPruyfBp8Ir91sGewQbhgcyTzBR@lC7clZnXbB0neboNoak2GKNlApGtkkMat0nIOk1NALC3saLNMljCuX53dPQKS69oAKfaOJ16meATZl@Zsczs38z/8iz/jW9vOh@D@Q@EeF57B2x@Ltw64/3kQUizC278M30rw9lP@9jaPpJzdz8NLExIRCfjV4THzaXyMJOrr41jpsW/DvtNyYIRm9YHWV0Q6jM6LFVEmgqM0vgLKQ3UB2VFIo1ym/EyvqeBujHI@j6oITmpqZDRljvnomDZnfDvCTYnQleQ31jfWijA8NHNXAUAysO6ilQ4HqKpl4ErpyhpU37UMtrOzw2Tf0G2zulHhJM8v629X5XchossQV@JaS4NBGkgSpYCwmkimLOuZoopJsXGmi2nWrIBCwmsQ@jSFHBBFRW8nsNGFTtMVpAL2cMzxkAT/JNDGQBVyyETU5FtTA0A5AMRh49a5aS6P7G7QTDHG91q8GuQ3GO0Uo5XleUzWeMvOh@dOU2yhZMAwv5zDcg64/2jOvsqQe@qzG/qU6e14WBr29NRx0T7rALBlSilfWs0XN9RYm5IFKMAXW9BHAAltBtqgYVrv3YFf390//OLo@HRmYxrFTE9HS7N0bSdzntOyjWboSE9xfUDUZwf505fPDgJSxrGKljcwRrTGMY3mvNymMV2Q@xtu8DSbNwXMZFQsPBQwjdFzB7QMOAs9Cs3HIu5yg4yZXBX15rbR3KmdO6mZ7D/O26yb0laQucB17tNW3TSbI3MOAzOuMzytwdcCq9@SHG1FD@18@XvkvXhrWXj2Q7S/LDAYk8h0PrScl7QFpmRQdi3Ps6LNVRyxAF@QNQGqRUQ1ytCQZpao4tgwUZbZYyqEyXNIpCM@kKU9s7oDYxjPMnhsnwQ0H@7SRk8Y8BwOozESjLtwXoaGghMa9oCoCGeG2hYN9XUvMPAOQ07NvpU7C/BBwRHtFxMbpWCw3rOtVkWvNsYstJa@a9uU5g9sa6jgHq6xhsNJKI2iYgGKO7gJaqzubDfFfjMWbAvL0M6y4xHQ69gdsGgIv2cGrhMYxbG9EQAHNjDZF6M@xOvQ48TEXsJkr9wcJAY6pgMkGriXSpRB67fXIXetZ47bVhd6GkXNgkj6rFiM9qTpuKnKSYMc5qT6HO124oT5pH10MYrpDV2znLY5VnD7R7mJ1AH/9PWbq7Qqz/AAbeYTe9va07v6AmGhD0WrjXbETQmE7e1QECTbzva21vMltGaHEQjkeDr0XoAT@lCl09cHTBnRtkifaYxelXPFyfpDT2W5GvZn18xhmQyNXeBBARqjlB1yWTZOjit4ioCSr0I9o6/vtPHxwRqwRlHTmuCmTFS2jLMPu6Bu4LhdlUA1hSRlAgsdMPyVEaNrGKUhRvy5TNlKtLEJYs0Npobc7VEDBFpQqVntcbSPJtYCOVW3t8uiNpLicJsBW@zMkRgAdo6YC3RToK@wRwaqoRCDWLswKLVAoDz90nQcaK8K8EwfWifTR8BknpoNjsnJRqcjUA4pjuJzYeAMiCZPTdhP39gu6DPL@QqNgCu30O@/O8eOvyO6/kn@v89r@cqNsmxXJ3lQxtSastyrFjOrK5nMsrOiLDuojjx@jAPn22XQdi40WZPHECm3bKsV4GfQjqrLTmVZ31GW29XSCqWA10xGvYEE3/l57WZZv80vPwZtIgs@Hm@dyrJPGxoLmla8BfywhSzns8AzN7ixjw6/weyXrUwGcdCWLxCB7/LnpxnqV85P8zRGrwglN9/tB2IkqauENTFzaA8noPAuhxJ9HSW6WMS@CCLHz0yYE3andv0lmvwwWp4wfT/OX8mQhwsWIdBQOAkho/AdpUDAsQJExNesrqogTH7zm1RxA0Z9TzZWFTfzZL1QyaTXi5V0iqWeyvkV2ZNvzvdyV8zMpRsdfV37tnl8eXz8tXqusG2WTu0eycU1@S3bLq3kpVR@pfBxM59/9@4dqMOsUdNqWlNt5NLNhsIHdJustrm5kt3YWsk@TV9EI8hNpiqlkgqVds7W2fmmrq9k1kpPnQqEbONnlRXBib9b8C2y9XW2j5@//Y9/@/O//Rn9/Zy@f21Z1sBvt@Hr9tgl@wCfyw7Df3J/aMfcOrpbnQ8KjDNA/axS0ygep9Prq@nTt7h1@ckS/NE/fMJX/F0iH@FNUWY/S1KqZqQ@pIrFYmpCfxfoLo5jg@ccvYwXffLFYukcj2ZY3Vh6yoCqJghR/JTLT0MYeXlzS3Zd8uhBDuvMTbH2USyXcQ4/Uio4/CPX0DtNNqzjHztr4d/JEP9yX13i34mBf88u8e9lC/@OT/Fv4OPfj3r05@Hfcwf/Wt/i34sP@Hdm4B9hv1XNMkD@u2qVI80E8tOf@d6adhG4EMq7nXfV3@3DPuUzkFIw6EvVas1M7va2ob3NVCriH8RlJXzDD3cBvs3bXG7nbS2TaRDejZoowE6uWeOloV/t4u0OgM3sNHZ2tItabVzLNd/WGljKG/wx/Ft8lGRogucr6KyOd044yL0AJrYLhn/0ecFzaRy/gFHOWba0k0uVDuq72dLp62epIrytR68YuIqvJ/v1vaPXEPv4xX79dP/zw6/2Xx@Dv9@8qD19mtGAZ54CwrVmQ0qNP8vUMtXhcHjx44sVDTvIbd5Pboc4TH0u5rj4q5Taq41f53M7gPSLi20s4AnllgNqND8yDlZKNVINJfMk86RgF64Kxcvi5Uv3KPo/OhpDgDUuvHe9Qq/QK7ahbbGC@bowKUzGhb57VGyD04S/Qh@cVqEzLnQLTsEpFifjBKjF//0jd/jyyAVoLqQcjgtDBAyQ1o42jp4yeO0eHb0EsB1A4T38WYVCYQy4jgtX8F@wi/R5e1GAgqu40RfeCoXzc6nB5HcmyEqtmNYKaW0jnbaa6xuDb89vbksb3zZIt1vfbjZwU3dTZtn0xXkj3ayk8v75eZ7Ldbm0Jldo1/ft7cXFXv2sfnGRxymx8c5y5mkm9xQ@1VpmRzyepNq1ypPzcg6ZMGDHVH7nyXltNYfujQxUQQn8dvKZT/xEIOFZWzqX0sr1mzdv8Pvm@uqau8jB/c7fhKH48yYPXtyFXvDBqPl56ZOO8SzfKUpjvXlzC/3bebqSFj2gwugEBbl4Pi51WEnGUYayrYKSUVxFVXZjnam12sY6eGxsqTmlgKMQnuRcHgwG57JG8y4a2bpWq3XP0yc41lLWAIiyvV6tnsu6d3EuN0pNTLue295grpfbXlVlVX1b3NmBPDCLkgrecnosu16a3dzG/5Sb2x2FPir@qSp6qsA39KypCkRQ1@FtfKOwHWVHQT/wwnQ3tzV0UrwbcDUUtane3nI/@FXUHQ61pgLhGCgY/0j/0PH8/@f/5Wvmg55ym0LN2WFr66rSmpjq2oayldkWf9UlIKwir6ZXUSVK6@lG4@nK6srmWuNJc0Vbwa@yc15rzumeVVCUoCkHba9aTGHFojzTKidysSSn0Z1KVQxxZoTtdtnqdgV7dEwowwddUppBhdZ2QhaOem61hvXPqEaZ2mTq7Q2wNQ8E7VoRC1Tn5@NCIUikskqrunyT0m8rKcyF3cpBEtFCKA8lXaFVTPlGXta9RrEp38rLN61bHIqsFFXSQtfXKpWVNe5eVpTi9kZpu1Ta3NjYKm5ugXKyUSjkWbG4VVrbWl3fXlvb2FrfAPmmqhXKcKW4IuAUAI5wblUqpq8bFRRclRTgoSgw6APip86lasvsQvZAoEG8TWfW19eX8iV4jD/b2C@Nl3ZW6FNbmfvZKm1lVjJPGyvb21iJTfL8uCRVcFGRr2DKOZmLBra1TZikcPmDrzssH4NKIv5W9la4q4jf/SVfGjAHBrWbBdZ2bdyx6HY6S@DZ033WMk0YvZm2HRxKAgNMu31ttc0lqdEfd5q0K7yaaxQ31ps5YIz34w4jZpB8Ez79Y90cmeb1aHRthp9dy9ffv9cH9Bl3fvjlT3745f/4w69@@sOvfvLDr37@6@9//hP4/iV8f8qfP/132@v4@@vv/@X/9sOf/wo8/xq@/xm@/@nX3//r3@Nfev8b@P5fMb@/Ed9YPP6VANYf//r7n/3Fr7//57@A778R319Mf3/403/P//9v8YfOX/3wp3@DP@LlJz@F4v79X/0S/3/2V3//n3@J///7//r3f/Wv/v6P/y05/ow7/p9/8@/479/9/k/@7p/@yd/9/vcLfn9y5@/3D/D//h/B5@F4PgTOQ8r1qT7f/1b4/C7UiHIBHgBO@6Mf/vUfAK/@KX/7Z/AG/2HQH4YviRD@8ofRC0D4X@Yk@qNff/8nfxG@/UEyYiIMgPwhhP15IuwPf/jl7/3wF//DD7/8sx9@@cfYSnNr29l6Nle8e@CQgojrD4iHETceEg8i8ihLbEkq0RN/hCdbItd4RVpfxfFVjn8y3PPjMiqc7PyjtA7vmY95PG2G5T@K0HPcWlSE0NU1Ci2A/lzA0HV8DUJjqOCC9ZOnCbWeI7LyEZRh0Gzzsdg84hOOqPDPfEyIdUxJ4Ush4vCNMlsK0y/NIcwT9hSCodekjnMHf/EFfJ7BYE@M@aq1LVaVsmyrymrsGUaswjuFo5PeoY/Fg5er0h57hqNU9N4DCvGhORtL73DsnaHoNR6V1SQI/w48nnEwBA1BfSeBV4b77MHzOxF/LBE8/BdaK7rxGwTAT4ZxP3jFXofgiB@Jx@DBLHjEqYkjbIyH6cb4zyJAAk5GAkJksvExWZhFJvKSwtfMTC4hPlNhmSiMic4zASrDZgDeFZjwlqYTsrlQBAYLQ6eKGYTOyTEITc0mCYPiBMpkkgTDlMlCZaQMmsatiExXMitkCbPyqR@BE2Uwlxx3fOL0XolKHocbYR9BJXx5ggzFjfImiArXqWgpgRU31kLAqqTQmWSgkeK0hjkApU566XefuWOlkJXlbHFj/tyBipMgEPcbt1yufldc25TgSe8jPB5NHNQFvI1nXms78AE8pNpNDoWAVDvdP4OwsyNWLBU01ig0b9Y2S2vra@ul1Y2N9c1ScW1je21jfWu1UCxsFNZLpSKorttb25u3Uu1rNtbY8fGPcuAe53L5EgJk1eL6ZmVShYTkJdVIkeMK5OQmB7ojInBO2usN2i3gDM4Nze49gg@THknsEXjBBwDj9C0Ty2aHRxWxuIImdqGKzlda5OL6tkwafS7nS@em0@bApUHsI53haaevABhQw2Ev0OJu6LIz16Uz3p6ZxoIYuz1@Xvmu5/r@7xDnme5c8qA9C49aMYZh0HMdN1z7fWvYWxDj9aCP5r@m948GYb/fAgRx4pNHeAY/nu268yJsstfHC0r5MjScxnUZspyG6CeHnz8/iz3P9uu7z6UN9uzo1d7UY11EWmcv9g/OwtdNHhokXQ9BfLP/4sX0q3jgOGaJrW9ms5qmwQ8@s/Shp7b8NohS1BbrFfJGobQpF7MXExMGMze53G3XapnFDRi5rsmPUzCGwrPyTvlpgEOnzcYdYvvtzeLm9obtSi/RQmW7yE2LLR9tKAHQtUMmrC08Zng0WOwJD/RCp2d1eyA8rt0wgu/719fhdNGbYG4onCN6w1q6jt9P/UAOZvwzvNtjyPMgv5kQeza69BwGh308Tg93Ng1xXcTqsIKkoaQolba31re2V0tb2a3trbV1GAauZ4ulLIylN7cL2WKhuFWEEfR2Mbu1tr26BjIJQte3N6UUtHyrk8@D5C3KMj0tx8BzlXbwgCpX69WkVNvsIKuysdJWWaodeoy2mLy6dV5gkFCW0OxtZVyVS2toELhaZEVZknVmsNTBwW7h4ECWn@ELTlXuFmS5jS/rW4XC5jNZNilkF@RmCRL18G1/A@c0ZdnCl936wQFCeI8vpS2EIcuXPIS/2MHLJkRz8GV1FQEwWf42BFcA4C7HaItSDflLofBsV5ZHHL0t@IN4df62Rsju4wsGYKIDHrILYbL8eZAI1F9ZPuHxRFbPg/LW67J8yF/qdQTxBRV@nRfqS3yp0wcSefAGnCvLXXB0PRj4y3ILnMi/smyAy5jo4NcHF@7ldIa6LE94ObAksjym2LpxKcsXgT/kA/g8f673hm2zyz8Tjz8NCDqEIGs82j9off55q9tteZP6/ucnFPTFF8/195OR1@q2RMLWBXxcTAVBl/3J9MfEoIsL3Z4f9CUEOVNBF5MLkzC80L8FzMSnixn1L77AoC8gaN5KlgAInz5EbuHnWR@ez/QWDwo@FETPcaslV5Blsel0FGJcPUsPOr1RvWFokOAr@hOSWGWUVm4HNIvRlppbfzLakjc25fIKPOUn8io4oWmwQrrAmJw@l2W1sd18Im@uy@X0kye59OPiEyZvbstleXMT@ly1covCTlFvOso4O64WwCOf38EGjU0QnqAFiD78zBwPtecmroQbudybxGdn5w3Eww0uuO3g1agPo4NrVFtu6IzJwPbxovqMFTcLFQd30Jj8tbRVASWkW21g9I/4s5OT39TeyE0Wz2V9swA4vHaM0ubOTuP6Y1OqtfWhDoOgZzejclnkcBvXWZZt3R8uFzdL5cZouZErNpeWCh@7O/KPawT7VgoLyaVXKH8gEHocBt9cTsLwQVVQXWYKHoSLS2e00q6k05uldFpNVyDtkgz0FOSk1TWstoDqMsg9oPp2CZJ75nAEfW4BCj6ds3dZBiJ6aGpBOZSZvAHKEXjj6cKzn6cwtM6WV1rrO7V/MvP57/7JvM98X/xIXNXbKEqpW6mNZ0GtbUupG@n25nanFuT4JZtM9EwwfGWPGetmlqXlNBY8vZocr9Wr9e5JPZiVre9Kqdyqu@amlpeXpdTOWU1elY@0i3AhppanBb5zXP3DlTLt/GJnKfNbrdLktNrTYHETUM9Lnon7Dtp4aQtfLNlax4roMj@V@S0/kIlUBZhSBWe45RRKAMN2R7hSvXPOC7TzXYoWU9jxTWfkkOFZ@SVqwope5jpHownN8LtXln2ztZqrkb2EAhx2e0tcYRzRYraUclzhBELCGGQIjVEBxXldFgMJkw1Ot99uvt16@/L10eujA/a0UN4qw6D8HHgkW0wX01CFT6GjtU72pdTgo7te/M75opIqD9Kra@nVsMrOqylOH3Aj0yuNRrHJGqvNZgMYrclUeK1WS0@K61uZtXJxk6mpGm4MKW0ipdEFDTy3mmoKMGubKrhpTrxUTNXyqaDtKMXNoprypdTWy3c4XxLcJmKVyJXPM7Z8u3ML/7Vb1tjZucUBEP7eiieE8XD6R9yDF3pEn0S8KE4U/tuxmHaRan6X2@H/O/ize8RLJm@sy2rqXbUGFf/24u1FSkptM7lEdZXJiwENtJsuKlMrDv2Z/tsVH/4ijxXQDlfCN3NnxWfrtSIMUs2VfD5/rv6oBJrW9vbG1kZK@g2Q6w6jUggNraw6Jgw0QEDPMbOqe9ZLHU3QnNDUChwvRx/w2OinwYUxgVLGUCtDO0JUy@J@QlOLedE9S0m/iZ/HTS/oK0nosuiSMNYhpsOlpCFtXmAruOcc9/ap0o30CGCNjCHtl4GfiiQ9wo0b@KoE8bLssT9UcearoEqPHglh6w81f3iBwDGR8MwVKxJ0A0Aevd32GR3cjiugfEOgjtsg3AE/nMWeMJ7Ip2bBNUzay4f5xhBeYR2OBZRmhVGOhDkWjmf/iEdrjTqIysHhi31IA0PjDhk8idSy18JrDah4Sx2VhX0G0ADP9q4KSlF0jAjgwJMrEGofdx0aCsXMsCKGd8hwCmJlWTFLmGRZRyRs4GsTkiP4DsgwHwDz3BVeArZyIbIVZRD4UCGAhFg66vrQoXtdIytqDw8ubTRVdhPsbVIwlO2wUrT5SsCCyuBXkVFCo98WR7RXIzITtGIzC1Vb4XtklDCe8IkIdSutDLP9Cq@qQUX6UjFAz3E9pfJd//Fj4@2g0W9W1H51iM9Mpg/d8aVi8Sgrw2q/CuwxaFjNyrCRyVjNal/9UsF3vAkB@26hrfmqKBuU3KkCLmiI5qvZDw0n953TzB40nAygPMqu/Lj6IatXC6hnZa1qMWtnv60WRTkgz2H1Q8ap6DvwRePBxP4j0EAyeiXhhUkuFbv6oaE3UXGzIWEmcwCFATz9hp3JNFXI3IbA2YQV@/FjPWPXxhU7l1Mx1tvVJweNITiamSq@lxV9Z/zkQ2ME6csKPKuQja0C8pBO0Po2xB3wqwCNeZ1GqHMcSa8cA3r9anXlx09WfrxSXVr60Bjn@s0sJ3@5EHEDIj9G5Cux/V3Kyo9VNkUSWhRW5M@s8mcaCEc5a2UyQOTsIJaSY7jyYwgZZDIB1rcoL@mCpMAwFTlM7Enip6LTkchkZ05H0/t0w8OwjbszIW3dNyxLROfbagcWjPB1PHcgS9cf6BQDw8SNbRh4Pn7yRAqyFttgIGcULi2T6ThTQPf2eLg6Tbf/8SMW7pOv88RwIHPDETIdxQ9j8dWNWHMl0UQNzveMBkZBMXBTuK1wicU3P4GwIekBcUh6YLwcShEkkpATImZVBEJtBRUEqVBOdPjxIHQQAson1KPDlg8ihKMBjXkOGlb2fZVkE/CTBS5m7VB@4ICmIj2CQiAOWAaryWogyNjjx0y87lRhlLGJfQFGw3jvM0WMNIMpZP4ATAEGYvkeeBTlIWUCuD3CENzcl8ho7XfLSOzNVSBB5n2Wb9HVaIuuMnJ8vjMd6aZyNLAuHj16n6muCYTgn4YhkB7Cbn@TEt19me0evTx@fbZ/8rJ@Cr8wtNyK33AS3B42c3fQAO8EalkObVAz9JOi@c0XBmMKjrXwfGO8HLDNvnj9gpVKr/ayeDohkD7FJ7OhQy2HkEyfTn/3Ndfr5q@tSyufvKIU73GjvXB0IWouuAoF0aHO2Y72y0fb5X2cpoPOXByplrh1pG/6vrgSKRdcL0kH2tDJAX3cAA@tUFyhRNsMAktpsstHi4gs7fbwrK5Fdwb2OIBEerpMYsiTU/uQ8OojGqsCR0vbW4VCmRWy6CgGjlLgWA0ca4FjPXBsBI7NwLEVOLaFoxhALnLIMLZeXd2InJuRcytybofOtULkjCCslSLnauRci5zrkTPKbS3MbWOL4LJUQE1quqaHYcW1rSCMZg@G5LkOYIrTnmuAaGkmJiRfm/GE/LaSnpvbBZHRYf4II5VKG9E7SJ8gblXhWGU5HlmeM38TntBXSXxQRwy773kglfbHeNcbMJ1aZrj/V5LwdBPDNnVQBswhaCnVA@B/Uy3zczG8STnaA4wQqsXwHZLjVSOQpkjXFXL2mRNcmhfMoZXmQuPnkLCQMLEN1AJJjmU50dNyiGsJvzjUJRSwSNEFMUo8BtZBcsd1kOeZN5qb5erdWSYAzs1yBikOd31eKqSNQsCrQVLq/wlaNciP6ykm1TaoAeJyWuKBqQrFA1KqN8Wy/Ovvf/F/sF9//7NfsR/@/Ff/73/6n9H97/HnP4DOwkphhJ/@jJHtBvz8K0aWGmQ1EiWi@Ktl@Ydf/BJe/6d/y374yc940J/8hZxdCwFBCHpFKX/@z/DnD/Dn/5Sz62HEn/8Rj4hJ5OytlFCtFIj1079mDHJDKCGwX/wlY3IGFAxFcF6Dt/Fm7DgFDiAkQ4Nczelw/otXfAGNC2pGBrjirRi9ZbAC1BhwT8fbVqO2B@oMn6FEKW3oRg@3zAsv10f9x0AVxvW1LvDbdRuUHjE5kYbS/z4rs3QG4@A0Cp4LU@UyXJRflFuOQjFuRs4DdnhNkABFF6CFmMDwVgL@ppHAxNdw2EIj0iLnEUHfV3ibc9CByAFn0X1QksgrSI2TMOJuTLogLBjqItNiN8TPVaF7sSSxp7sYyzAhbqaqDXKZ9oEhY3TSQjwpeZj9AVQJJAvpjYTFF6JCdhpcVHOi2ewfHUw1GPy0QMW8jEukMKMqk@V74iKlRXwVNa7VZHyOr4jQKJRXm4lzG@ZFlr/@@mtZivkVkIe8tkIQYoXiIiMMKiaDSrGgUiwIcOYwSdasl0pTOFDHgXIxeUYJTxYTUclkEXNhywnqAdGAsSCf/sx27JHfq86CJomcFHazwGMgi82qaCfnDsmcGpPVmQQAM5mmOl2X80EXZuLMVtT8lEjthE@ithZDSqSJNQqinjRNpbDmitvzai6Z4R2gi83MAzMqFX7HjHIPzGhj/f6MpqsV0ybAL6bv/WInEBOhhI@A8YafSnRQ2DX@AlgvEkeIsUdORYUhT10MeVrXLlPmXIIK/vngOOLEzade7JBiHMS8cocmnx54OnBhyOGiFhy7aPm1iJ4YdvAbyruO65l@/DwWi@9Yd9J4IpDhdh3o1bJ4LLIlrvVFuwF@VFyyXwl7NqGF7vJb2BE0JxRqnhcXlmMNLy5A@bQ7akRAfNUM3EaclvD6dnDF0iuhans0UFw83n2o3g@T9F2e7MwyLpWjgQhMQyZ1BgM6w7Rh8MV6eMGj73KSYBH5lY@gkbaGCp3B2HP7btd0XDwMCVNPgT@MYCNC@mBAuGSZnmVGDCMxiFaMrK6KpF9@clL2ZQmvKA3Sl5IAEsTIMm@axkhZb052Fwuz48mC/E4/Hd/TOL6nd@PbsTx/OI0zeeJsDz4/LetVJYIAESM0Vu9HIyvOP5tBJ4FK6I2XC/MED0axTaZMbcS0DlHrIrrWAf7Ihm8@bRgWiH@1iP53V2CQfP@h1UfK7OkE5E2f7gKlIZofrKUrEP1QVSNbxFh2IWvvPTAvMdChEV6WySS4HNyNDg1zMDAdvI6SfwLA9/A8GjTN8D1ZOVV54BycvKssuywtrqK9i7Zp6xOzrYiY2RjcoMQnpt4mefWwgqOgI6Hn8hullUK2mFDF6NQQilRewDJ69kpVF7MVj2KF3EOLcYTh4WL60cTdtGjGSdAqXwNxPZCgKTpYkI5zHEwGE37SkE1HgAVylPc/vCZf4QFM9xIE6MBvXC1mo2zVu8TniRIW6QE9QhhXSxaZ9usH3ZYL2vhMHX4aie4vKc0yhImqQS0ntJNFNW7dVeMxrgh4kmslD2PJ@5juwTwXYzUOLBJhu5/WhcxA3tVt2zCUOETuc2eNuc6MTEA/rDHXWdCrXMwRqGFKknRDvI6uyvULVbLAeQjPK3h@BU8ECGPQC85QQdlQrw2mvCikrw9iWovwaRioi8aoqMbXEWOxpMCNE7m3YZ7GwjyNmTyNRJ5hC0hmGYskGYksRS1g9dxVBbbZGS6QzhiEI3d43CW24eO4uodrrzdpK122six9lS6DQE6b6fK@AkI53U6X98jhp8un5LhMl78ER9S20h/T5aBZYAQPXsnxFP2FCMd3I13eVdRbaYinqgb5aulyWKcQ5wl/JYrc8unVllj1d8NZVROvC0elMsuQY3x4uFisRjNL3wL8U1RxWi8ELlVZaYUi4wAk0WnEegyeD3QbGl747inzuo9yMDUl5jeiORQIz1RjkyrIJSOSR@lUOimMOGIYSpOP8AQEUW6W52PEijMjs/vQEblbeFE7EDuZP1FPI32grVB4AyLHJ3HsKH1QX0kQvAIfhicmXoTnDDpBdoQRGgOoc9BCor5L31EorOupk1957cdraHaOACsxF0ThtURgYzIddDjUTSmzgTtIMgmF4mqfFU@DH9EokXunkpFUEC1zQTB5i5KhYIg3fvWu4sTSIWoJEYSBjUKTt7KwXyBZjEGRrItpqrzxAQoxmdOmo9hMZNs94aR4XNxkqa9Y1A0FaXmWJLmSYhISa3h6wUgf8tyjdRk80@DThq9ByjEe6q4ggFjKMBcuX91P0N9drr8HCnVAhKkM5inW87vSWfX6zl52CnM7yna2AjEwy/bUucpRmENEchgdxDTzu3htRsXHm4u5ks8zDaFPafsB2cIxwT10mx5bcFioJXhXSc9LnJi9LC0m1KxGYl9pgdKiYU4CDi94iGlUtLtx5QWfV8UYgn00PD65gr1kBccrD@FRAbwpkvNW7o0cMq@K2jYdqBWtXPBVBxetxMJzjGOeIO7Jfi000QKPo4uTvaNXL76BTndzc1OdXYrAVgtpo35cunOZIBy2lLJ4FCWenk22Ez3XGy6dO/KsSRl5gDKg07oNZz/RxlUhy2LyfKrtQjoeN0ZRAesyagZ6QiqhqqNjl20JuvLrspQVXQAJ1Fugd5ZGa7hqhNyBCzoXF9R9XVygcc7FhejFsGrCZaTfpMTF2aXIXgNcCWsm0rj8mfPecAJg1Kd9TsEEnDjJjduhpADO4TBIHaYaOUMrMHbA@SHa7Ris5SurRZydOOyEPoQHGmUopTUcwpbW8TAYngpj48QnmVaKfJa4ooMXGvgD16EjqemYT1Lb8XoFP5h6JbRHzrVOZiA8FzrDJoYRN8gK1sVch9814PO0uK2SppAD2mSZ2dVoxae0DUOOS2vATyoOTT98lRIRwmSjBTRu2WYfUDoF3p0zm/zSglrpHVjdLjBSXtwBxw1cznRImnM7ud3gBL4U@0q3rXZwFrywCaN7GMQ8MJBTSRyh6LPSBmhT21mgbPQFwqKZDMNjEgtkpEWx4LsJj03u3MrG0i4pEzX5LAYfFeEtKRdYs3wvu@XhfW9XuhOjM30@xqemxaIlyYHYymVwaJ8kTm@t0jqlhjZqA0VOycFpfujkZhO6bQSHCyp4rGVZeuSQ4EELMGZw2xpQcB1U2mh5TQ1NUh32GVstSXQDhUuTyzxbgMFX9hLQIQySIrLcuk8IGPmztvwZLiZKj1IoCzmvYfqAldFNp8JHvMyWBDi@oIJNmTeB4GU99rIKQ41HczJeUuQMQMnIqpyABPHF6scjLnlnk4JQBPHwqabYpuc5FE26AlHC6PJeYUZcucOwlyx70XwwYdeLg6m4oWZH2K/xG6@y8mu0wCrzTKjv0PCwVhTdlWnZnSsG5pr0QDtptkJ7iDuJjkb2MHGIxpLl3IUA9SjEoShnyPzrM78MX8AhG4AEMpHFgkK0Ue/FjSiCdtR48kShWYl1KUoxjg0i2PFBoHSAnln5M7RafQwJqYuF/k6dpzYVKon0gJw/cMiSW85pMiUVVscIKQmC1yb6h7avEhm8B4LrjuPn9Xxxq7CxTfbTzMkOs/3GdjO7YlRlZg4t3en7I@@6fdl1e1egLLDB@9bYmHz4lrH1NYYbSkqP@e764kY1TxvoN@kEim06wmk5ON6Czmg4lxmjPbx4mkaasXB7UWUJt9XDJ4s/Zbkyw6VspR9wITei7jc2mlWnWqj0G06z4mQy6jBTHWaKGQU9HhfVCkhaPu3SGDbJKjK/wl4Gpot4OCvOrbodduw6Rs9N@4yuzYyv6dGesaAB9fVBvD1dwajD9eI@HeQnvZ9oiLNedJvUVErLDeINJwMTRWNo9WnjncP482i0sVaZDccSPnqEJsoVoZvGC3AjDUYt2zJABhE9UcVAc8VyWRjdGwz5FgQU@lnck@MCPZCCwZUg1HAHE5HY4lEugrLsxEDWFOy71OxDYgaxWsCTF3iUvgfReBRO3kR0BqCp61E5Vuh@YTphP4P7JNQKWpGzpSAs2FGB8ZFvaF/DBah/tAsCHjtMRCUbY6YKi17ybVhoVECqWi3Ngx69H/UH1L9rHF9BEbwn6GKgW16YUvNHeOGYwopIDCtAGmsAHbe4C@8KFMt41QR1gRMLtLiN5UF4x3TYMyBs6Hj9IMhGXNxBeG2X0jziF1Ep0AnyiSuOhkhLxVBFVQPh8KS09CBdZjTPUAEv6nIqsdD3EIplXRDch@C@PuwtCO4h7JG/KNiDYLyeakGwBcHc5mR@uAvhXJNaEGGIs2jArhdD92KoW7bCDabR1PqWC2yFZTIBYUMWYLxieH0k0zNhes6WeO1wZkuwF7RPYiseAVlaEY0H3yNuoVA8W0PhfBHLk9OE3bB7MxOTT0DiC8oJxC7mr64k4LMYAtD@QJSy2fAgc17bYUET/KNBt9PF2gZirbKPH@/CTDBikv@KzYD7eA3hPGeshJxaERx@e05UrzzRB5Fofhphmh@XboEOGpUjaJSlSITwthW1644F@iIkVVHLibxxSKmyJ5FPw2@ycig9IjryZnE/HUsz3IMjTmqRWdaKnMbDqaoj30NKHXrkViQscB@WXpkhpx/GziVj1yB2SM0pPjMSPCNa6acW9mGlSQF@1KiJNhUuaA1QDWsCwTno6bxe4zKBA1tOl7k/3vVjJYFZC4Dx/YoXAGC4AzhgzxaI8aBPtByN2/yAnC@U1rI0hc@j3EZkCoTVQ@j0D9C4kHCiyx7h9QdJkcTmkGYmelhupFdtuslNFY9L@vmFa3CjsfSTNOLIZvmJuO4J9JJlVmDhxpgKu71fDv12lLmJqi@h7/jKYlkRVHrAiQ9hwdsFhL6XyZJFKDVZguIjusJ@cG@XRJs853dK0dLFReATTGvxtr1QA0OsKslwxJkDDAJAUY6nygqdqxaJTrG79WIYKDfZSAvDW4c4V4DKXpHi4hyHcwfUecd9w605RJF4CFoKoobpBZhZnUC3BTU4SKcZF1jNnMhIT2jTXddtK4HCJBQGghBYQEOkLN8uFKpVXL2MsofshNLLusKKOuh3K@CzJLyoXwEPVD4FbyISK11qNhVsNjH9xvLpUiwKx94IsgpWd3AyiEsfVp72x9ihCvRobqJA4uOeL9oZLOQ89cQJ8SDv6g5OvNHJXzS03pHRP6wIjFODgXa0f5jq4HbOLAPfIy12D9/Ehy5WxdJQJw4rPZhlUishNjs7MmYTHbTxm9RSfuR7dE@y6VyBUt2aSClmOvxahDJeLZrbwolYvBlUSBOa96ZJHmATqCnMTXPMa0XcHoq7tGVV4nv@aFKoKOF5EDQvb5tXbdD6uUX8wPXH9DuBwUJBGw2GLoWIjGhvIPtofYz2qxdolVaMGAQ6OwQniqPg@g33nfC5qFyRK0hFPOtCjYFoYEoSuPK5LGP9IaJivq7RlHzN1I0eIoG895EPp6C6iJNvJT@oetzLhqTAxUFw2tyKd0Bzc5gFaSf@hN6h@PheRAf3oSlE5HsxTpFowhVDbNcdIJPjVBum3wECcMI/Oj3b2z850cSJxnxFAFcR@DwxmmDQhkBx86@YJsXVANyOySvlERYWYfP8qhFwkr9EI8xWkAmbwjWSk9MK93vyEuSK9DZTjDC@yqMTSWg5Wbz5SMuCsJoegB6FtIuSKbFkuSBZEDlGikf3UkM3DDS0fWn2XcB4l@6VLnJaPIrIgU6kSJB/Jszfb2CezRB5Hp6bCc8lwjUezpGKYmlGz4sileOR5NRNFO@WyVG07ExeVQaFPnxFu3c014vhXbkrrq/BIM2KItfCquRcGQbsJAJysZC3c2qfhywl0oQMHoY3eLjg75Ko@RDLRNynyfzxKYkKMsnGVZiETHGp5lg2v406CiEJy3DbCk@O9U1sxxulmBAR4iQHYgKv5sVmW6tGUDLFQOJQm5FrO09lTUxJPVGm0VD5BbbTDWtOG4lRifLMEOHG1JNAPhS8FANBMJHRWNBya0HiiUg8iYHFWEtBtlKwEzvZwKFo0028itPmH/EnaOxJ5IJ4qfmBjzjmY154vpKVJBAJ3SV5PpmS0mTojUzuKQp1Ry8S5T2ZhjhfSLxycQRq9OgG5iBPk6@3ddyR014K5URcUASSYobuYYigdBShGLDvoirEwFvpN/kV6XO9D1qhbY5ZHXVqnU5IkhKLmXhnso@nieFJlcwfDQa2JfbNsWtaLuPlLJbWcbEnghhTGjTpEA1wePwsusTiIyTS2BFCvkY7jijAx1u06fZVhte7gWjtWAByqEl1Z8IvhsVtZiW@pGiykc/vUafr4mNI8JrjrSe8bFeTgoVbXtQOb9/OEFQgKLjr8VvE3U5Zkn40sozL3c9ZqVDYLBZWizGSBVPVBW11LX4JeBhQKhQLhfXimiTtuoMJNx1RDBVhreUQYJa9wI7@K@BN8wqvX5Pq0GNQRDzo0je9K7OtSdKJ2aY54NaIKIKsjPex0ykVtI8efUC3wvOE8IZiP8uvIQYOwyf2z/xsAIMMl7MSrtEOTK9vDflKrnvFL6IP1qU7rm271zQRjUvCnB6YqG8OgSgrKkuiRPv@BS6ku9B2fKCGLm6J1VvuFZ3TIcgAeqqFxxvRAquEm1QRQjwzfsVkDBPIz7B1q4/sNAcB3MUSUSBAAIrWHhnmnThIhMQn4hBcf9t2jRGefKAHNZMH6edSW4HmbnoWSN@IwFQrlCyGO1Tw2fPDU3Z6dHD2pn6yz8B9fHL01eHe/h579g07e77Pdo@Ov6GjXNnzoxcgXU5Z/dUe@L46Ozl89vrsCDzk@imklClAqr/6hu1/fXyyf3rKjk7Y4cvjF4cADcCf1F@dHe6fZtnhq90Xr6Gz/jzLAAJ7dXTGXhy@PDyDaGdHWco1SCZF6djRAXu5f7L7HF7rzw5fHJ59QzkeHJ69wswOILc6O66fnB3uvn5RP2HHr0@Oj073GRZM2js83X1RP3y5v6dB/pAn2/9q/9UZO31ef/FiqqBHb17tnyDyiVI@2wcs689e7FNOVM69w5P93TMsUOTaBeIBgi@y7PR4f/cQHftf70Nx6iffZAXQ0/0fvYZIEMj26i/rn0PhJOUeqkC97L4@2X@JSAMlTl8/Oz07PHt9ts8@PzraI1qf7p98dbi7f1ph0oujUyLY69P9LMP7WyhrgAHUgnBwP3t9ekh0O3x1Bn3G6@Ozw6NXKlTyGyAMYFmHpHtE4KNXvLRApKOTbxAq0oEqIMvePN8H/xOkKVGrjlQ4BartnsWjQYZAxLN4Mdmr/c9fHH6@/2p3H4OPEMybw9N9FSrs8BQjAEzM900dMn1NpcZ6Ary4E5hVCjg3S9XJDg9Yfe@rQ8RcxAYOOD0U3EJk230uaA5tOS/NXXK7cwFvdpVPTIXcfQjP7tHePmh8/Bw@OfJ/DZ3OVnLxLhEGHU0YCK9iFZT6qou22Rp1L/BqeByah8n4Cnbf72bxJEsV79s5l@66DI4vlFOCVOri4qv6BYxzTy8u1OxDUibQuC@F2OV@VyxVlNF29TYN8xNzS3FC1R6Ls3Sy/GCL@FzL43DyQWX5fNsUydA4BAEH00Ti0CcA1kbJSFYjusNiWdISc3KuiE4km54sCpY3XR9@nI/RC@8bYh4gnLndQj6PY1hCA0@WYyH@kAkduiZOXiM7AKtDWWq@aV52lUI8OxzyiwkqNUhDcYcwDOwq6j3JW2Z3KnluOj0hi7Y8pKwEx@0Ex@Dwe3nxTZCMiXrRPCqZwqf26KEG2FBGoBSqPCsyFBLWJ8pjnhz3b/O5QrUSHtVCx629rH99@AYHc4XSWmXK/3noz9sWWvXh2YHQ3zUoXZMez5s8AjQwC4dfQBJrwpdU8/lYGtDKSJ8MI@NZQD2MdG21oU/FrrpnUreOJxDx4xji6aEz9qxxHHsQw5@f1F8@e31wAJITsV3bWt/cqEjiRCNv@HWWP7/BfPBoXKIuaNHXFqhpFBRrJbug9xzMHEYYOz0Raw8j4tHjQaWRJ95LHO5M5joCP7@MTwNhcX08wcnBQ8xkPITJk/nN20tSwK9zW6ZgACVRVBVL09fHpOHroCoRDxh8F7I9oVob4w/CDpt/0MTDAgkGEixm9gfDCXAuDC5I7skHgUEnjW3IbAujaHLAxwM9sEHihEGZSVauaONIb4K3Y7UIei1WNLZXqnZKCUgsTWMRHIJHR1pCFseuH7Rg7mmBz9eC38D5jTh8EYPwKK368BTIeBCmzAWHI/I5Z9EwBORmrQpV9PhxmNMOw4lUVSDF5/@TR/PFWwOhwg0a2BTgwPIopHMYQpPQT9Mqu@GciqemIJyK4FjxDpw7rzgCSiU4cka8Byf0MQ4rOrCPvK7DPKQgyjdBlJCcCTL9TvQg@P8NaTIH/g4MOAF6RC2Sw5YzMh9ISYLKaQWjVyKKdR1YjMXM1CJqxr2@icDcxiumFxZMmOGN@cISkEDUziTw@IYf2arMIQAyOc5rxNsvHpBAjbinw8jpKbXdR3yl33OM/kAJDjwNuooZuM0s6VzZwEQOX1S@hF9gsexe4Pl1T2kfLckMHHCBFGtN2Ge@zGFkiiRzsND5FZr0CFs5sSaSoRi08IidCqJpBY1/LCyMol6mHYTegiq6@DDVcDkEz2xMCPxgBSQQIGT7FC@wIBvkWUNE55YbLelplp@JXhxPHAcRSP0yOyPzZ1/v0JgZuyJhq4xG0ZglwvmsLc7EbJnDa@wubA6dbLQjaEz5jMzEMRMxFxmqEYHwVTWgOnWy1yH2NE2J/Bpi/9q5dPDWDZNPcQUxtMQJm/Et7hp7qdNhm/bDyi1HmWeQrLVk/ocO2a0bfL0Sp@Zo5A654Ej/Mz@iCGic16hdQj8UUUk3LtFTDnjUus5ZY3hQXjlR8uDMSBgz0InA85T@24UDAuSVKRtYJp874SRSmXdk1c8C9QVdvO2Grm/QJeaZq1AoQA580GBWqEGIMupNaKQ529oIv8S2BTQ@LYPmdH2ttfRRX3c6et@yJ2R1@t7tOXnfGfkDvHFeluXkbCAetIIm6ID70GRvLKftXvvsGTQHnEg6ffX69Dg58Reb@drlM1@MfQF5sGeUszQDvoN7Uny3M4SqMStsIm5j8qLpHponFDMtNK01QQ/c@OMRA0G@/VAz/vzVa/a56Zge6IPHZHPJXliG6YD4AGWKrDD9Hpc0GP0Acz8VubMD1F1oZqfCTIsmdcK5PUlkIKBlkbUUaIqAsCeOrca5@QmwemxOUJstcFSudjCp1HMHYrcFTpqissmnODsjOyvh2dhvDs@e42CcD8xpbga6tWCuD@cSuerU55O1UBhPd4YTIIo0PXkDaN83d6Mx2mwBEKXF5KRBXR8v62njtJ/tQ1HxKi0hBagHgaZqWld4GC9Nwz2kjsjOVkybRXSriP2rWX48cCA6ErUnRbWXxTPZtSxb32ZnJvIuO7Z1A0ZY7HSEyVdXQQ985vpDjPqyzlihVCwWc8VVnKJ9fVrXqCHgNzihVZIOXx4fnZwBIcURRAFjhH0mEp8OReXWWECOHB6NCqV/hwI5iA8Ss/SOiIcqeHBOglzhKxZyWYa6N3Sc7oUS@kl1mKZkcUre9ehgVtxtAyyUaI6Qq3@NwpcvjVBOMehZOhpWHO7Ku5YQT9otSQneIW428JWN66HvKDH5gQAwx@QHqTwaGbTFsUJQJ32zH2JvDYPeXecRpOkzZUOC8blUYI50No1aElBPjcNpm2gj4ePpTH3/yvBAtuhXwHJowhJsOQKeIdmkhqXRW5ZtQRsAvIyeix0OF1dBRdAURPzEWYlqPDzLEDskwmXOaVDQutpuP4zKsZKkcLOd8B/4E8NlqS4Ms3Gk5Q9Ms00nUY0G/KglDNegldvQc/BteOXoDCYpVSC7SQ@EDR55B7JvZOPefNxL2eJ1LgWlAa4Ktm@e9XBYzwFBiU6H1EjxRFxlzgg7y3CdV6Vq14EhMK2KhFiwkRJADLK4KAVYQX0TQ5CL2CWL231squ/pfZaYkA579AfJAITFV3XNZEAAHssunDMROJNWQwSmtnAGyPB9SNydmANLvmB50e4UN6UpvIxQuIkaEvPAwiPK@dyAy7ou/mJkLaAYXyM0aY1wZmMo3ptZBHjTMYuzMSFWeEBbLGZpDszcXJir82HmBEyxWHnoXNGGOExFbMFLwU/bcEE@IiGi4n/uBqKXtu3ZLl9gCkvftd0WnosJkgJyw8ckG1Vs3JtGYAlCx0P5Js3keZ47QZEE6mJvU6C7sB1oH2aN7QQzFrVzh1eUCKjytkR7whj1XdScyIk/okWRU04cDopax9TpoIge9wXZjWBlAVL4yGUWtUy0xInHFzknk/QTSYpTSQRyySStRJKSFO0En6pdTIGiH5/JkgV6CVklUQ2walhBBamvj/nopkAb/GiaBo/kTuw4LDUFg2DEhsHCPYMYvSlFR2Aklu15HsErmeCRxbe8LNORooXkeVLjwHSPxADFSoRP6JgVRxEFUgUZ6CU8XkMNkBHl2qEkTkxShQXmAVKi2B7u1VLiuahllhrofNUQY/nYscWzbhANcJVehr8VpogMcnFkeSQ8tkCIQiA8HW3RgKEsr5ZADhakqGemt5iAgxqUuPwmkzHeDShKol0FkjuEyZ0zshtAoT8HRzlJfH@1D3od98UeJSYaTlHhw2PihZJnjmF4RmvMBIL6n3DGWnjyMyNC6SGQb0Q5N4NeI1mKhbGnu5J5cWK9SkiFuyIHxA7ptDDy4t6GSIdzCCjvePQY6V7gJLEgXdAFp31OMtJSrCFtJncNi0uoJNliQpenzc4RwMkqD5DLTpVKih0VI0o43Y1IiZ4zwSRK7A2vwWGf8YOCOSBVSqRC@i@qcDR3jDfshfGKPJ6o9kUcEcIK6v0utggjB/V@F1vwyLFqv5stgrOiQ9JS@mm@SNQEJwEaJYoRA80pxWVQEDCOxxpPxSKEJs34WTGmrczBNiZVxVynNKMqhSQSR8Ml86DHmFdMSmzkTrAjEK8R1kYzKi30ccal2Q5PvBClD4dINTnZJfDanD7oCQsd5EB11FTxSpIwAUhsPgkmxsx9brtJJwal@YCFxqB4Kmq3l9zdmwAb9CoFdVahDE5HipDfmYt8bvaUqmiIVZ69fye0LhNYo8GT67UxtizNWfGV7sEqE8MqWbpYDSVJvABS7kGQcg@AlI9BEg17FfpLcqY8PAfYvA/E@fksDHq8hYGUgAGStm3hJDaOg6/1yX0wl0DZSpFNnc6tysIEkZ58H4wn0zDo3PVeuBonPHs6zrp9MD13@tSzhZRN8socjEKsUrNoZREtkto03hXxAlWJxrbaZatnhSOB1P01zc@JEInRlLgXLgKlkqcWhcCi9l9cQL9srFqT7YEjnpiGAW1Z@sTmoCEh@AwT3yoWJogJsuQ4VAQkCXF36LTwo9Hq9OkSeKD8wmTqvSV5yid8YpNORSgal1gJjguGcJFwCnqrQL7NG57dm39qbv4DdwA6TmcuAhS/j/P4fFJqSqRHqunU0PpBfdnc/my2XHG9berst4c38sczRS9B0XFjOjRqx7wWvf9dkEVZghr4LTT5RsAjC5D8bC6SuNCui8kt5oz6LdOTHtLUeQoNH3yMtJhzJSmVYnUDhszi5CG6AYqORzZFlqgGIyP4bDTA9RqfG3di48Y5MpMz8HRcvA6eYmsyZkFztH1Td8RRRKLD7Hq4fhHGzeLx6Li5i3KwHAMI7Zux6c93/M6PtilC0CL5DrJW5tc9cjVdV8@xyEY5CbS4rqlMkmNa7rtAwQm1GopVnlZUAt7BxdAVrpkLfQkUc3X@FNhDtKe7FCJg4kVZigHvFOi7ebS8mJijQUjKsGoeQMp56lY4y/0AdWvyUHXrvwElpytUirmF9iA62PK9Qm16kE8X3gYHX/fnHN3y1dnBQeLAk9YkGBX0TW@9UCjgITgzt9vhAgWuEltuPhk7j3Pi@cH1F95XrTwmTd5nN/c6O8QBomJsXJpAPsGliRH0N7HjtHA@x8FdOe99HpOfwNNmZMZphcbtX50R8xFIJJ5ZZu@wgFi@dyy4XBoURz5kEFACezNIjWrolRyYyQF50KODJ@qEJmkEjMbNYtcCLnxUazfSI3HFI83z4XU86k20DVF@btq2m2VvXM9uL8l8d2gywcFBPEGBR0FTQt54fLoeIsvMK8uOXZGBURA31zY12@3yO5bw/lw@@0l7mTxzgCtpCvZjJ2Z3fzxQ5MZbGRgTipzBYmaY3MTtPV0ZuiiZltDvB8sPJAO0HxS7rw8Ug@g0HRn6QLGXKnIBRqt4iSa3Dsb5lF0oMhpzKIkoKj8XhtPs/thI1Pnoau9dy1Gg6Bgs4XY52vpN1UslWRA9JK58Pi52kIYFDkPghEcgPizFbQUPnfrtPzi7jTMHuLmR5njDLbGx88bi5Qgm47FlsathpwPNi8/E14KjxgJwJCpzRbJSQNKIivXMb0egzyjpjp/mB9ihqc3pxDESiDRKzSxLj4adrTRA@J3KKAUtUDQ/oCeaTXyZg2Z9MKJ7UiJ5RtNwaEAxK3cwwQUmkKTPjOq310q9XmfLg0yG1evPwJHLsfqzOttDj2fP2B68P8P3x9XS@nqFW87tqTfg@SzwvGXPAAZ1QXgn2x68QhhdtYRDKazi5Xx1OVtZvqju1Cp@vlF/1sznu@D6u9//yd/90z/J18XL9/jyjF4ab8NImqbll42b5ce3FXxv7DXTy63G8qCZ7laQy1Dcv/Z83dZj28Q04x/kXtxg57yhMtBo1Wo1zdIfP3LX@TByepETLzGIkuv2oKdTckYQatV0Pf34Mbh2qukfp1U8uUP466H/B/BnKspyWi8m0tLycf109/Awfk9QeP9oBzVNXHDXhXGa5fgWFOpdKlg9zzWYprFmjr0L0UOD7gseMYkiS6PFKEfmO4FkUDrELABAzUFu5tAgrZprFDfWm7lUKiVzMzWLMOP2qWSBxA2juLla3@@S/VFgwURhZC2GiT5rl7ltHcHIgETE@BW@a1Xh7fFBpnDQ0YR3irMbRvfdyvwa10nser3Y1bp4hsj0vevhubXRzet08XoA0Jg622AaIDe9g/Ey1QlaAjKsXPEOHfhsNb0T99@wtWCtRuxhd@1J18brKGkbgn8N7R3oroorkm0nOGcQc@ApW2YHlxJ5GyGKxbbBkapl4u5Sx8D5euhoHRuPpeUqVHARMehkwGGoM4iTLTq4i1qxHW5873bAqeKl8cGFy1RvGTouieoE10VsOnSFpw9a1soAtMEBj4lUhffIcBXLQGbTwuTh0awJ40AVKWmJDHeTArMOGmgjV2wGx@OrgvXkXr/fB3nCmSw0hgF9rY@DO5xuAOJgCo3OcoVGN2HvbOfdvAuZyf6PsubZlbiNL8iCMDtLLGlSdnw7razyUuHJr44@FGQeuL5vCRMQUV1k38L333oA9Twt8cwE18SvrF4ZUEFTUcY2b52cpcwx8DvOMPHTPCB3KKTghkRENItEmz5ucZZKWLrSveUozFrm0DL4JiSe@1Ig5QZ00Ab68hNJFmYEajk3tAwqmnI4Z2J/p7CxpCqP4BCdcL8v80dGL1RqdaJZYLzD8Q3OQxk0QiYJa@c8IlIEMeQEApAkisCRpn0EBR8lGNQ2u9YwkSbLtzOLnZu8FLcB6bGxvyNbwhh1pyiLVjfBndGhaHgn6B2YNw9AHAVhICm3uN3yfN4LCoP9BbdyClPyItGRFFuz/BHKpQCdONbQkoF82IyzyRqibgt7EcvnfMzrJGJVFtXCnTkQcIEilxsrtEeeAAipMU2TXANvzp2iBojVqWYQSeNCAnyMgZG5430kyaop8vLq4p3tjBAP@CXA9HbOTfD/mPkmqrLl4SGu0PggFvIBqAKRmXYLYjhGpDeEIOe2wGszUIFRDFu0M8gb2aBTc/Nv0bPEL1uPMg3xmMoqKLqo4RzpIIPgKLBGOl6XU0mD8kapm8nUuTQ/FeEmOBshzjFcoxaigoZwfNpWHKQg0jziXT30tUFu/CgEpRC83gZnNogjD0JL8KDOREVQ56t3kGhoW44yPqqy23kME4yZA9kfUELoHWiKEgdOsOisHxEvbl8/h3S3NGVSHw3dw@E/vA5Nc2WEjdWJaY4jZwhagw5qp1AgdDUvXOBs0JXR/0BqONa1BZXNd4bo/v/X3hWstg0E0XP9FbJySYoMTimBkDbQ3npoC2lvCViuLFKDXRuvU1qK/70zb2ZnZyURl1LIpTdZ613tvF3NvLfSjlo6Ho2El6iiK9@H@7ebH6fT6q68K6vzi8uzErrUWNpJE4g5nDQtv8G8Y1beqtaj@KxvpH1vxbHvviwXC@Ij@rECqqpXs6KZNnvLK9K/zAmGCQJwCdfels7DhwkNIk4o1jje7ub36zkOP2w@7@Y/31Fows@P32Q8P3F7NxSi@KOlKLmRO/fNgghIeWBdmubEH5mIJeo58aFmD8KwbyU1gZGIAQDaHgByTbM/5MY6GLz9slZg3BrRlAa1Ft4S5F3sWnLw1RAIvB2AdNFMztHcVP0RkD9ODlEkcqFLL7kg7pxxZ6WGCIFVcc11shR6KYMZJt4pria1qmJFE3QKBXPUlI3sNKyt96FW2bNvvs7WD6v9Ui3rmRXt4kpVIVA88Bc91EzO2sfZ55avecPRKxQinXFk8LxE18XO2cHt3i7pLk1KB44qoaASLbbSYFkq9hL9gP1Y5ktUQoWMZEx/8RLzY3q4emRshPtfRyHCCc05aZobDtjLmDsxIhn@LPoWZvU4kybcDwKFu/F8yz5ZXPPBjzGPMKdchzOxwf0vgR@XwHKGIZsllKJq1deWxYeJk@bVa@zXrYrpBKvzXvPSTEHlsFnHtxtVZDhp6z6rTHcQ79h@ajl7RM9lnNBBFfdDekYzzm60jDLGjWgOTiMxiMx@FGCrJyOeScDlbDXjmOBcuiSRHOsH3IZIFfqn9LlLvSNjMksH3Bs10QueldGIXtGZXuqZMSD8lebUIjpVjW4psOnDV15FSxEs9jVnmp7IFymAJiY7IM1tGhwFqu0Ddf53QEm/hnCSkn8GUw5AjtJhNBqavuY6dIOmv9dtb37PLwG4sRHhThsDRBfPEV3Hus3RAEZmfylk@Dc)

### Explanation

`QuasiQuotes` is a language extension that allows you to create sections of your code that are parsed according to user defined rules.  These sections look like

```
[name| expression |]
```

After reading a bit about QuasiQuotes I came across [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11679) "bug" report. Here they detail how QuasiQuotes can break the way that Haskell parses list comprehensions.  The example code they provide is

```
let x = [v| v <- [1,2,3]]
```

When running Haskell normally this is a list comprehension and is parsed as such, bug when running QuasiQuotes the parser thinks that there is a QuasiQuotation and attempts to parse it failing.  Now this is pretty good, but it gets better, as pointed out in [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11679#comment:3) comment by bgamari if we add some cleverly placed comments we can make this into a true ambiguity:

```
import Text.Heredoc (here)

x :: String
x = [here| here <- ['h','e','r','e']] -- |]
```

The `here` QuasiQuotation works as a block string so this code sets `x` to `here` normally but sets it to `here <- ['h','e','r','e']] --` if QuasiQuotes is enabled.  This is the principle we use to separate the QuasiQuotes code from the rest of the Haskell code.

The first thing we do with this code is to minimize it.

```
import Text.Heredoc
x=[here|here<-"a"] -- |]
```

This is all that we need for the break to work.  Now we just tack on a `main` function.

```
import Text.Heredoc
x=[here|here<-"a"] -- |]
main=print$last$172:[128|x<"b"]
```

Once that is going we combine this with the break we had for `NegativeLiterals`

```
import Text.Heredoc
data B=B{u::Integer}
instance Num B where{fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B 128}
x=[here|here<-"a"] -- |]
main=print$last$172:[u(-1)|x<"b"]
```

*Explanation to be continued ...*

Answer (score 9):

## 178. [CoffeeScript 1.5](http://coffeescript.org/#cli), 9839 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x             -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO 8=,_      x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps    # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]      #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqTqTqT                                  #
############################################################################                                         p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>x._++++._+++._^<][4O6O@]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                        _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyYyY
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"' 
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796los*81''TcTcTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

 console.log 178;

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcxtJkiD4Wbn3D@5LMEEJmQSQQIJvgIAEUWSJVZLIJimpqkGISiQSQIpAJioTIAFRLJvZO@udx9rdbk/vWG/P7VT33J7dmN1@GNvdM9u1GbMzu/26Nj@i5uPY2fU/6HP3iHzhQVLdM7YHEsjICA8PDw8PD4930/C7v/lNCj/syO1NOj13yIaWP2Qtz760PI09nbAnhu2vF1clCaFqXmfUt5yhX5JSTGfMdky7Be9s6F5Yjv3R8sC/yNjAczue0WfDrjFklm8aA8tn7mg4GA2Z254fbZWxvb77wc5hzL7tdABsaHkDzxpS@Bpjr52e0W@2jKmQ9akEBx6E@@yZ1fvU/zRkptvvG07LB8gNxl66nm8hvGn5vovRNxkb71nmFNItADU8231Re/XFVNA2Y18AicagZ42Z0fSHnmEObddBnhTYyavXJ0dTMXSdvTnd35/2LbKvcq7D9kfmxXTQKnvt@UbPmMa/xmqjoXswnPZfZ7WO5RisqG1rxenADfbUM5JRqDiPPLc1MpHVw64FFGDxtO2ehaw6cftWnCifOZbVYv7AMu22bRIcs8ZDy/EBn68xGzJxZfd6rGX1IAIbCInSzCzzXTbyY17NntHVTE0ygapq5I0OlmKeZbQ4NVLb9RiSwfoXPWYzczBgPC7r2QC7X9hiFgoN@wjhva7PxoM@8@0@BA9Nt922LPbRGnSZ1HIlBh9zMJVa@LZsAYxjBYyxBlD4yBgXZQW4FPDnyjMGA2CHYNHQ7oNo28O0zyzDt7HyQBTfclrE00FYrVxmOHF@sksbChc4M/IIt295WDAa4WVdy7MApREKtnLl2UNgNvKixo4sw2OnnmWpySqWSBISczGFIWaE83pnJ713uJ8GnvMYmjEYSilv9fRHX0oG0yps@bwM34osl6W9V8/Y9fIZunmNgnIZeIqhssp3zM@fnVnwHevNfMe7kQCrBFzpsbw7GOaN3AAIzA2BwLyBTnTlLovaoBdLmO1MlUVMEjhUC0qDHTjsTZZyZo48D7VGxFTjAjLdc50O8BMy640c5IfDNgpQBKYLlT7LrEvgGtQyKiP3ijh82rWh0Hwsklil4LqPGAraD6RccDRI13d7I4KDmP4QRR24AlER40GbvWFtw@5hFAhHVJxqz/JHvSHGGTktLHnQbVZLYwEZpttCoL57CckZgJQ8QPD7sVpJRAEwFIRLWcWgH/7Fn7U6HcBTM03XawlxfcNarkla2iBiQfUxFFjXMXpEFsBlMXUeHRK4NHp2yxhi8s5EJEFEUKpX7qjXYi4k6F3ZUIm7xiVUfKha5tDiQs4Ve5b1jQuuS2wuuZDxvtGEgqUEKG3Kdo492YVSMi0pRTKT64@G7S2WG@yxtJ9/pzwuKY@XziwgTtXUleV8vlMGgdNWyAve0rdJzptaQvf5Q8N37ZY0mAy7rlNkOZPJZsUdWI6STuBIZ9NeM61qqHwUtWxXTK1tOy0lvQOyWIWE02rZrJh1u9QoT0WPJwlorhANVldLMVVZApVDleIy3zdsRxtM2JuccMXCXP8cWY7BWswbGTPtd8k9UtSwoVy6KCCghzS/Z1kDpaDpKqoJhJubbwyYl9MpHCLDJbuRSafSmXjWCQPkNJFRrKyntotqqzfoYpsGTHH8ATQUHsquaYD0@NheDMG6yLImyTU1MqBZSCdeWWnPYk1QpIEcUZXkVQ7j51BRCgxRFUrWZKsVq8igBKAuD/0ZbdxzryBBogkbGVAdDiZqdKBoIDLPSI1nhKdEPsksXTigUBBb02JbuaYNlQCrG@h0IfOxvAH4apHDADZeSWK6p29MAIvJW92owjC7DXWpD@rBmzDTQp0DysfiDQomMqL654M9hZZVIVdcX0/WsZkqNvTytdyPQUl/zN9akzDztYTJAC1P27piPcPpjIwOmnQORDFM0xoMhaKCnPhDUEXT7Q155kTjqfldafnJdNrUiASWR5QGKnleeqIpNFC7CKMu1wNlygxhlrKW7YFa6k2mUweAy6nE5fcIkiDgvbyAhMACACGzxpY5GoJWAwG@6tpmF2QWqXO4XuSN0HTy4BVPHTR7rh0mjcTo1UdFScuHXkjGQhQ5LNFZPNC4IqpqwoMKP@5xO2bD789B7IYkQkMQ89XyhgaydwfOvuu4c5ACI0O0CJIM4eUAltgJ2pvQcAVmF1XW0AgNiwjKDLQG1HyQv@5wOPBL0E7Yw@6oqYGk5E@9ycHw0EFhyQ@9iT10ubvZc5ugln2on/kghbw5atrjqQyRX1iGH3zpEgywts8q0HJ/OwKpU9JtHxQm@e8icCxIJsVNKPivDIAEpAGjlLZPqngflMrJxDEVWaOqpEGlk7NMxoorq@DAWCFfdt0@aiH2lgwDtPTAxLedNmgrofNJ5Rtzm7pQ95Ndl05rH1zbUa7TS0tL6VK6Cpp9aekxuHbQ9RhdGXA9JleOXAinoYtiZMmFoXWKgX6N9E09wDxWG1hsY2yVPtoDxaiXSquNrFHXxbOITxVUHWg2gM7hA/Ck1UoFnaoqV68go1qzncz9LmrnE9OzB4IJXxqXBn8XXFglNtj9geuhAVvGRvZ2nvQrHrSCYLSaXcVLn9ULZ42z67NW5uwmncXYatmoNCFTkJ7S1zqeO4LmUq2vlXJ6Q1Xrq9BINivpQnpFUbZyPUjIUNWHW2rG4NxW0hZobeXsLA1MFfypm12P8I2zRVUNWQV0YMMMNqGS1q63IP2m2lAzaYirprPQxaik08AZE5ngU6ZRMolB@yCAuycvEr3K/gWoR2b6PbQlch43J@A1v8I9W/QITaYSOyCT04H2EkiA5rIVdm0c18k5IzKAyTp14wlRdw8hyA8bD1SMdgIGEbftMVj4UHEngSWDDTAaM7vQoXR7lvaWbAuZgeQzrK/aXHPmiLcLmulHhQiGCzgHPcOEmplEdyazM0AIgprPzw9RyzOIp20d6pbclUdoGUzDQf61bDK7R7bfRfaCaYR9Aa8NXEWbGxp3i7h2wExotDvAaWtsD7kRDoJwglGeG76iotlX42YTWmvY5CNRQRee2mPXhA6LBU0/hvLeH9tzLm3PdZDJ2h6gBoktYxlMIZ/HXhCjWu2g@Gwxf@chB47NeOsx3saxTjPX9E2Wd9ye23HZCgCgaGoaF@wDxwQSwGgbQv8QevofiUG1jgs9l6QMWthe@2jk6RuroflsIGSe4LUPoCzY/ExHAAvyfHLw4z1Q8fp6oQD0B28F@oSZjGGZziN6miwCEONrPZQbLMkfW4PuxEuIk@@KbiDIk2vxisk75tDJHwBVooZ/pKjxSs59oJ4HQa3ANS/ve2Ti4FhEvJuQyD1Yc1BPRXZ4tYEcpqa80TdgRQLpTIFH5bsPyu@0O7Iky@y6TD4DE6FYZfmWdZlHhSNDW9wFWzcHSVkeWVNhNDHeJw3dEZhlLatn9@3hAQ0j9Ry0PaJ2NQjdhQoWITiyraEkOgyROYIjSlFT4XQ4/N4YWxRfsujJXh0@2zs/qp0@r8j5ke/le3YTJLhlnffBcuxZvsymPyl2bAEyEf/jRe/YdYcVXlwXPXbnJ4Vxgugvnp2/OHh6XDv@hhNBaHy7P@oZSEppeQoAo59QcFCrYuN8bc/thya1LwpieRVZbyUGaLF/KULXMHQkhmdj/hvo38chV82UOqbJci5/DT0F4CYC4jCsZg4GUieTQUgalg09BeQWocShWc1rBp7b6BkOysZ6LXF088IXRxKYr/XCDSL3nZE/iOXsWtfJ/3LYbmOzG3oXyfsih6Lei7xXyZsP6iaSCtgyEzQXOMS3Rvj4YPBcfDNBc4FDfOscHw4iz0c3FTIPNES2Qchw0HkurqmAOYBcLE9BEb5wofl6Yfs0cRCXUym0k84kOTD2EjadHIUUo0EXlrucP1okxxFRDQIhv3CxjxG5zguavo5YQhT9i95szDa09PSTAJ0hajaE19x@s00/cwBKYiAClBQOvCNXvsTBVBwrccHusq4IjLpUhAy4ZTtG/pge2LmaR0@ym5ggpmm1R2CS5MHmRfcdYLntLYJsN5v2IlDgC5IePOeAeaPmPLZBF687M5LAEowfjrxhz2qJ53/9vRYUwGzxdI0JmWGh4xz4RrLRXlhaIiq@0M/8kiWYD6OebRAbyHUXStPAwVujFzrmo8b2hOVyXcPro7UjCheEE39ABd0iZ5xyz@qNWlbwnJ8IsTg5XsFjO3afcgRPNNep@7Ug@tRoC49PBm/PNVqEhZulthWVNi8Xa8wNtJjdA1r@HnQGgyIsmoWA3v9wxH9x4uGucrUH@J3PlVJSyArrRlO38q5vNG3rFjnwjItRy80NLjqUaSRtY5G080qEffhcu2dccOc5OuczgGfRszsdywuei8CuumBpkYmYv6LHLaIStHOMLBfjNpxej/8uAgmmeUPHYj7ZPfr5HIEkETGh1iBrcfIxF2OTPcXYntGcoKnc/XzJwgTJgADFUzEzmcIqNmHhUHI0zTkYLI6P7R7F396eH5vPahICMW95R22GFsnuG71csRVzLlTOwdhQ5JoDSv2hnNkzfBCSoWCzdQnFQj@3CS42MiaKS@S6RWwjcoKZgkWDzlGcgW26Pdsf8JokXhZpyenhuggNThvTTxQV32b524JuDzbgudA1v6K75hAHfhfI0T0UFx9zxVHtmGBo7iLeme4VfheaDl330uK/8xuzj3OpuocKyvVIMmxzTvSWeZe44tQh/czn4sVcqoZmb65/ib10Xa9rOT4raoVgkArnbYxejw8Cnx4cLpZp3@65PnSA8Pc2XkBHx/f573xpjrPNNpwcDcXF3fOjCaIGTBMjFwsK0@h13N7GVidvwM/CEh95bdTs4nlfjRZqJF2/UyOFho/r6OK5UJVfwP9dwkDDfR6O68ect7Sj89SXGA9enEHoHuBk3fzM7Re2KKaW573RRQXgmd0rYxI8f4vWYhF3g9ZiMCGzGew6jLC9BY6hx03p3ya1tdtTa91PJ82g3bwrE7HCvehZoKHpd6ZIWbGgf2YMvVC4v4Zq90bWyJqrMQ6bHyxcZnWLrrg/UQWRjWUxbpMH5uGoTQj1UXQK70U1tt/4dquCMXo2VPI7rZe5@m4AtvYA@9FH4DhCx2zEjjMaJAo3xrvjkXN8O@e6g6Bmu60EkRjyuRpp624bKWGO@xZ9F5nue30Xur5uH2wG5x7lL5DSUBf/TSAmnwjzBxvHEL1b8ZZYOAEI9irYH1Cq9oWfw4HI@yme4qI@OwFvb0OvzLGGE/xdxO15irTpur3PKR3Qpy0bzTIwNnEp3l2lNGPriLlgFo1O@DjS0WwvGpfgbY3oQAL3sLO8sKCPIEtDahzuU8ozY5m3tFqxkc27@pHQYtPgj@@ZgXsRvcdYuXVtS9u8lWBujrpNq2fwx3hj7TZ829rqfUyiQWDn0kg4jp7z8fJowiE1pYIGE2CW3cr5ZtfqW/R6i5FvtD6M/OCxEGjs4ndOsJan0d8F8QY21HkHfxNj8zGraOg6lp8fGl7Hwu5JDyeNhO8iPRsMKs9l7kHf6Fj7dwpXNPqAC4VoUjbmnD8OUeJz9yZEu0OT8J6f61xYEz94zrePJyaU56h/K7Z59dzEQc47K7aWnzuWfofZ53TdrtO1uh5VjvBtUfUAiRzyNda3ZQLo7xr@Ba6MIp0Udeu6fpy7PbfXuw93USdyDem688df93DRcwuifhbeidGEAPG4c6gOmm5iErXhi@pO1xpBC@W7Q3dg5ehtEWgPB3X47/wh5YPDtM/e2pbX4rPCOMJnDO1mz2JXNpDwwY9PRc4fMGr2XAMX391ixANngud9hqBM17tzHKRjuMPBgB7ng97Ipx8ays21549Rltg@UXofYbCHfEKei6zVcZtm176LpKZlDB37Ii@qv3idL@ZJZUw5t1nuGXprPRt45U00FIJKPPwEHwfzK779QmyRuNUg2R153uRu5ZCcag2HVflkADoWDcCIWbE5wdT046qTYHXFLTMSYhJtoUSRMY2Gc84qgHWiLxwOSqyQESzora4O7@CS6ZoXd9oTCwcoxfwrssq0Y3PI4D89inE7Gc@FfoPeofJ81PHVuwW32wK7Cn/mCkmtwwUEJ4z8nnsVG1CGqm844jE3bvHF3anTrMf6rRMgJaa/OK8dHtyNzOzZA5//sly7ONdUmJ07nYWaGAvGkk5AyNv37xj0XQ9XCoMlkTM9yzdxgBuVMFeOXPM4bgeUca7HIuAAdi79s3O180yUZEOX@/qV1TFw4dELG9cg9fzZtg8wT0/b3gfxj0aGb/9o5A6tuTinp2/vg/Kl0bHN54kiCBAG3BWrVPgjoS3Ra7Ygrrq2Tws2A8ciQwIk7XZ9OD3iHm4ewlA@FX1MW0vCRch@Viy9AT/bEzsgfC3YZpSiZUq0JDlYospSuFB6hCph6HoaIzhFMTIZVZV4JBxd7TgAFkDRRg9cBM73kPisZ/tDgrXbrF5ny9fjUqGk37AKk0syazQ4VlqOvDce0A6NYx61vmw0KsvpXC69nD5zSqyQJlCr51vzQY0EXNumB6czyjpzDL4IDd1BTst8cbvfpY0j0Hy2oBl@Db03UsWux5do8/X/pzhN@1/@siX204Ct7rO@DZUZGIG7zdy@1XWvHvN0Req1wcDA/TiIA4q@x1eH53ZrzL/C9ppvo3Gv2Ov90y2xOF9sKYOXI2xYYlTwQsWOI67MG/JC49SEq6xEwmGsIFOm2xv1HbCQWsOur4EioUV3Iy9aPQMuBHOGHpqJrSw7YC0LJ8NoLSX1jHque0GrmpGS//KXfEsCragUK92C5GkrUixFXDip0z4A03RHQHWA5KPluQJEQSZDNR3huAOIvMX9VVxnSHslQBJzwU4BTIbvFtitnbDcHkvjpj1cf1y228py7fiLN/VCo/Id6@et//p7efVa8E1@mNve8OUsC0DKNyhX8eB1CI5C00xeHssiW7hpi/YohUIlNooq6KbiClb@92m/F8mddUUr/2m1loNaCDdSOT7UD3hVCTWvNJVlZcR7uLmTIVuHBHH3hAEuvkOM1lHiKnaMsjxmn1gXZSVn4to@eOMM6eHGiX7labDIYTW@FCX/zGqOaP71sqgVVyuUneXzyk6VXJ7VcnEDU/3d2bhYyJ2NN/caeT9gztnZ@GGh@DVwzwXje/lRHivQ3qtn18tatfDpk29MmCzfpMt8bQ3U8uXro4OjvZPT2unrE@DmDc9sat/1@kakKVAWaLFe1@3RzjBgi2db/t3aI9Qg4RuAKwpbNtgO7m9VVSm@Do1ABavlnLzMnSEI9ELjse@IPi@@b8XCZwGEZmrbTGhRdkSCJGQm7cc1aDaQLSwXrO7QVQg5giuX5qhC4pHMKsClHHDpnjxis7nkJfiYPKAY72bU7TjmoQBeRRCzAMikMC3MLw/nmZub@Zt/gBwPoF37XXNMOG7NMULclmMAjKJRjP3awYvXx3vJSCBO0TZg6Ol7uNm8TXWLbyjk0uWKvWuBZqJOsi/2qoS61WeXtk@daJS3NrYMPVAuWB1pGYaP2oWvbGe1ng@avNUC1dScDFGzgUrXaEkdX1eXc5icAmZpYUObZbKEsH5ldi8TaK4rE7TYex55meAIsy/N2XR5ZuV/@Bd/xjdang3B/YfCPS48hbc/Fm9tcP/zIETX4e1fhm9FePspf3uXR1bO7i7juQmZiAx8c3DEfOrnI4v6xjiWe2zbsO20Heho2n3g9SWxDsF5tiLORHiU@hvgPBQXsB2VNOplSs/yGgruDSrl82iK4OCsRou/rDHv5NNWoW9HuEUWmpL8xvrGmg69XCt3GSCk5f4dXG3EEapqCaRSurQHlfdNk@3s7DDZN42eVdkoc5bnl413q/L7kNBlgJW41VJnEAeiRDEgrCqiKctGRlcxKlbOtJ5mjTIYJLwEoU1TyAEgKno7wXppaDRdwSoQD8caD0nxTwJrDEwhh1bgWnyjdIAoB4g4btzIOS3l0fohXG4Zk3stXgzyWwQ7QbCSPE/I6u/Y2fDMaYgNvQwE5pdzRM4B9x/N2eUbSk9tdnupMr05FHPDnpw4Lq4z2wdqmVLMF1fz@oYaq1OyQAX0Yg36BCihzkAdNC37gzvwa7t7B18eHp3MbJMkyPQ0WJqlqzuZs5yWrTdCR3pK6gOmPt3Pn7x8uh@wMk5VNE2DENFczTSZ81KbpnRB6m/5wq3ZtClgJiG9cF/ENCia26fpzFnsUWg@BrjLF5bMpKqo1zf1xk71zEnNJP9p3tbxlLaCwgWuM582jqfZHJ1zECxHO8XjR3wtWLdclKODEcK1yvw98l680TE8zCTa7RgsfJNoG0O4i0HSFiyJg7xreZ4UbfXjhAX0gq4JSNWR1ChBU5qZaotTw0ReZs9dEYu2QyYd8o4s7eA2HOjDeLbJoX1S0Ly7S9uOocNzENuJAv0uHCijruCEuj2gKsIBrpZNQwWGF6yfD0NOrL6dOw3oQcUR7V4U2/a6kLee3SwblfqYhau@b9vEp/kD6MMruKNwrGF3EnKjqJgBfQe35I3Vne2G2P3Igk2KGdrneDQCfh25AxZ14Z9ZgesYenHs2QiQgxhY7MtRH@Da9Di2sJWw2Cs3B5GBj@mAiDru7BN50PqtdUhd61rjlt2BlkZRs6CSHup6tEPSwC1@Thr0MGfVF7j@KM6Yz9rVGeOYUTc022lZYwX335QayB3wT1@9vUyr8owM0NZSsdOyNb3HNFAWxlDU2mh/5pRC2N4OFUGy7mxva11fwlX50AOBFE@G3gtwQhuqtPvGgCkj2qTrM43Rq3KmOFl/6KksV8X27Io5LJOhvgs8KEBjFLNNLps2Uyl4poWSr0A5o6/vtPDx0R6wuq5pDXBTIipbxtGHXTA3sN@uSmCaQpQSoYUGGP5KSNEV9NKQIv5cpmQl2mYHUHODqSJ3ulQBgReUa1Z9FO1pitVAztXt7ZIojaQ63GYgFjtzNAagnaPmAtsU@CvWVQPXUIkB1C50Sm1QKE@@shwH6qsCMtOH2smMEQiZp2aDc5@y0VkdlEKKk/hcLNQGQpNneOylr3su2DPL@TL1gMs30O6/P8OGvy2a/kn@v89r@fK1styrTPJgjKlVZblb0TOrK5nMsrOiLDtojjx6hB3nm2Wwds41WZPHAJRb7qllkGewjirLTnnZ2FGWW5XiCsWA10xGvYYI3/l57XrZuMkvPwJrIgs@Hq@dyrJP22sLmqbfAH1YQ5bzWZCZa9xmSqc5YfLLdiaDNGjL50jAd/mzkwy1K2cneeqjl4WRm@/0AzWStFXCkpg5hYozUHiXQo2@jhpdTMafB8DxEzzmhN1qXX@FS5cYzbJYvh@Xr2TI/RWLUGionISSUfj@ZmDgWAEm4mvWUFVQJr/5TUrfgF7f441Vxc08Xi@UM@l1vZxOsdQTMFPzK7InX589y10yK5eut4117dvG0cXR0dfqmcK2WTq1eyjra/I7tl1k9/tssuKCD/tdPqnUSl5K5VcKnzbz@ffv34NBzupVrao11Hou3agrUfrVzc2V7MbWSvZJ@jzyVZViUT0BUWFntm0P/FYLvm6Xjl1TUvzz@DGlBF1O@GfcT6QuHMELggjf1OfCGespdrZpGCuZteITpwy0beNnlengxN8t@OpsfZ3t4edv/@Pf/vxvf0Z/P6fvXxvsgn2Ez0Wb4T@5P7ZibgPdzfZH3LkMdneFdIJ@lE6vr6ZP3qWlVNVMfUzpup6a0N85uvVxguE5eh0v@uR1vXgWZTPGBcxx6M24D4v7hewImc0Ek1KfCyelVtjqxtITEAYLWh/8lEpPYrnIy5tbsuuSVxdyuc7cFGsdsq1KVsjGOIefcZABkT6L8hSFRG8s7pViQTQWwXwunJQKjhHK1Y12gw1r@MdOm/h3PMS/Nxe5NxdvLo5N/Ht6gX8vm/h3dIJ/Ax//BP5UlB0hzuFbKODTfgHHwxcW1AP2OXBS6rtKhZcFE2Uy@5kXoGnnges83F37GD5L8Ef/8Alf8XeJfIQ3gcx@ln4HpSOl6ql65Xf7NBoiK1JqZ2cn9aMu/Xn499zBv@a3@PfiI/59e4p/99CGUuof8HNvfgwklso1Mrmbm7r2bpwpl8U/2Bfl8A0/3AUF2rjJ5XbeVTOZOhVsvSpKeCfXqI55edOvdv5up1FfO9w4fAL4Mzv1nR3tvFodV3ONd9U6lsQ1/pj@DT6KspxfOVtBZ2W8c8xRPwtwozJl@Cc@L3h69aMXtd2902xxJ8dSxf3abrZ48vppSsfX9eidglfx/Xiv9uzwNUQ4erFXO9n74uDN3usj8Pcb59UnTzIaqI0nQHy1UZdS44eZaqYyHA7Pf3y@oqF5uc2tzO0YIdOf8zku8S6lnlXHr/O5HaD9xfk25vSYUswBWxqfGEd9Vj@rT77BPyn1fue9knmceVzoFS4L@oV@8dI9jP4PD8cQYI8LH1yv0C109RYofFawXhcmhcm40HcP9RY4Lfgr9MFpF9rjQqfgFBxdn4wTqBb/9w/d4ctDF7C5EHM4LgwRcaENz87h4UvA14a0P8CfXSgUxkDkuHAJ/4WeTp935wXIu4pnN8BboXB2JtWZ/N6C5l7T01ohrW2k03ZjfWPw7dn1TXHj2zp1kNa3G3U6qKMhs2z6/KyebpRTef/sLM@tI7m4JpcJ4Obm/PxZ7bR2fp7HCjTeWc48yeSewKdSzeyIx@NUq1p@fFbKoWAGIprK7zw@q67m0L2RgWIogt9OPvOZnwglPKtLZ1JauXr79i1@315dXnEXObjf2dswFH/e5sGLu9ALPgianxc/6RjPCp@i1Ncb1zdgJZ6ly2lhRyqMTsWR9bNxsc2KMvbVlW0VTHV9FTuEG@tMrVY31sFjY0vNKQXsy/MoZ/JgMDiTNRq91Gjle6VS8zxjgiMWyhogUbbXK5Uz2fDOz@R6sYFx13PbG8z1cturqqyq7/SdHUgDkyiq4C2nx7Lrpdn1TfxPub7ZUeij4p@qoqcKgkPPqqoAgLoOb@Nrhe0oOwr6gRfGu76popPgrsFVV9SGenPD/ZTr8o2i7nC0VRU4x8BO/0f6ByPk/z//L18zH4z9mxR2QB22tq4qzYmlrm0oW5lt8VdZAs4q8mp6FXsWaSNdrz9ZWV3ZXKs/bqywFfyyFWXnrNqYbzGq6RRU6KACVvQUli4qNq18LOtFOc2wTpZNcRZQz@2w1e0yHqLHIJ4MH3RJaQaFWt0JxTgU6LFaRRlgVKpMbTD15hpEm8Kgm6qImd6zs3GhoLJys7J8nTJuykiUzG5kARlUDkKtpMu0DEC@lpcNr6435Bt5@bp5g335FV2lbtz6Wrm8ssbdy4qib28Ut4vFzY2NLX1zC4zkjUIhz3R9q7i2tbq@vba2sbW@AbpNVcuU4Iq@IvAUAI9wbpXLlm@YZdRZ5RTQoShplQHbU2dSpWl1IHngyyBenTPr6@tL@SI8xg839opjtvRpBT/1FSiereJWZiXTeFJf2d7G0mpgyKclqYxz8HzCX87JXAewrW1KN@X7Ae6dqlTvj9sNOrqhkqvrG@uNHNp6H8btFSBD31xNrXBoa/mIlNvKsxX41eF/bwlPhWPSgDnuFdsssJbbw/3Mbru9BJ5dw2dNy3KYb/V6wcFTV67Xa13ZLWtJ8i349I8Ma2RZV6PRlRV@dm3f@PDBGNBn3P7hlz/54Zf/4w@/@ukPv/rJD7/6@a@///lP4PuX8P0pf/70322v4@@vv/@X/9sPf/4r8Pxr@P5n@P6nX3//r3@Pf@n9b@D7f8X8/kZ8Y3D8KwGuP/719z/7i19//89/Ad9/I76/mP7@8Kf/nv//3@IPnb/64U//Bn/Ey09@Clz6@7/6Jf7/7K/@/j//Ev//9//17//qX/39H/9bcvwZd/w//@bf8d@/@/2f/N0//ZO/@/3vF/z@5Nbf7@/h//0/gs/96bwPnvvk63N9vv@t6PlduBGlAjIAkvZHP/zrPwBZ/VP@9s/gDf7DoD8MXxIh/OUPoxfA8L/MifRHv/7@T/4ifPuDJGAiDJD8IYT9eSLsD3/45e/98Bf/ww@//LMffvnHqIdya9vZWjan39llya3fAw4BN@4DB4AcZIktSUV64o/wZEvkGq9I66vYDc3xT4Z7flpGE5OdfZLW4T3zKY9HhrH8JxF6hjsLdQhdXaPQApjKBQxdx9cgNEYKjhs9fpIw5jkhK5@eMACGyDFgAnzMCRX@mU8JZY4xKXwpJBy@UWJLYfxE93bn/ftKFQGeQDA0kdRK7uAvvoDP0wpj1CuFR3WLVaQs26rgEUEIWIF3CkcnvQMuPIC/Ij1jT7Ezj97PgEN8YIiNpffsPVKL/lUOyqoShH8HHk85GsKGqL6TwCvDfZ7B8zsBP5YIH/4LMxXd@A0C4CfDuB@8ZhBJJmATy0gcggez4BHnJg5EIBzGG@M/ixAJPBkJGJHJxntiYRKZyEsKXzMzqYT0TIVlojBGaWaSqDJsBuFtgQlvaToim4tFULAwdCqbQeicFIPQ1GyUMCjOoEwmyTCMmcxURsrgitIVkehKZgXHztnK534ETZTAXHbc8onzeyXKeRxvRH2ElejlETIEG6VNGBVuW9EMHNM31kLEqqTQwZJMpUENawCmnPTS7zx1x0ohK8tZfWP@oIGKQyAA@41bKlW@09c2JXjS@wjPuBSnLYJs48UF2g58gA6pep1D5w46wVjbkKpVMbvIdKl6sncKEU4PmV4saKxeaFyvbRbX1tfWi6sbG@ubRX1tY3ttY31rtaAXNgrrxaIOVuz21vbmjVT9mo01dnT0oxy4x7lcvkhJVPT1zfKkAhHJS6qS3city8l1zgfLEsk6I0v2GhcB4ajONY04P4APkx5I7AF4wQcw41wIE3PQB4dlMVOJ61VDc51PW8r6@rZMXDqznBZHLA3iH@kUT7F@BZiAQQ57gWtXhy47dV06u/OpZS6A2O3yeyh2Pdf3fweYp4ZzwYOe2Xj4kjkMg54beASD37eH3QUQrwd9XDdvef9oGPb6TSAQh6E5wFP48XquOw9gk70@WpDLl@F2C5zhpP0WAH588MXz09jzdK@2@1zaYE8PXz2beqwLoHX2Ym//NHzd5KFB1PUQxTd7L15Mv4oHdnGW2PpmNqtpGvzgM0sfemrL7wIQXVtsasgbheKmrGfPJxZ0YK5zuZuO3bT0Dei4rsmPUtC9wjNQT/gpr0OnxcZtEvrtTX1ze6Pn@itbejp9auKf9BLXfW3rfMG@7ePKZEB65dDC8CYeJT8aLPaEB3qh07M7XdAtV24IAHXr6iocPnobjBWFY0ZvWdMw8Pu5H0jBin@Gt3sMeRrkNxPSmwWXnkPnsI8HhuK@xyHO9dltVpA01BnF4vbW@tb2anEru7W9tbYO/c/1rF7MQgd7c7uQ1Qv6lg7d6m09u7W2vboG2glC17c3pRSoAbudz4Ni1mWZnrZj4qlrO3h8nat1q1KqZbVRbNlYaaks1Qo9RltMXt06KzCIKEu4mHRlXJGLa7jMdlVnuizJBjNZan9/t7C/L8tP8QXHLncLstzCl/WtQmHzqSxbFLILGrQIkbr4treBg5yybOPLbm1/HzF8wJfiFuKQ5Qsewl96wcsmgDn4srqKCJgsfxuiKwByl1O0RbGG/KVQeLoryyNO3hb8AVyNv60RsXv4ggEYaZ@H7EKYLH8RRALrWJaPOZxI6nmQ31pNlg/4S62GKL6kzK/zTH2FLzX6QCQP3kByZbkDjo4HHX9ZboIT5VeWTXCZEwP8@uDCnd7O0JDlCc8H5kSWxwRtmBeyfB74QzpAz/PnRnfYsjr8M/H404SgAwiyx6O9/eYXXzQ7naY3qe19cUxBX3753PgwGXnNTlNEbJ7Dx8VYEHTRn0x/LAw6Pzd684O@giBnKuh8cm4RhefGt0CZ@HQwof75lxj0JQTNGzQTCOHTB@Amfp724fnUaPKg4ENB9Bw3m3IZRRarTlshwTWy9GiSDXHNcJmPrxiPSXuVUHO5bTA8Rltqbv3xaEve2JRLK/CUH8ur4ISqwQrpAmNy@kyW1fp247G8uS6X0o8f59KP9MdM3tyWS/LmJjS@avkGFZ@iXreVcXZcKYBHPr@DFRqrIDzBHhCN@ak1HmrPLVxfYuZybxOfnZ23AIe7xHAzz6tRHzoPV2jV0Lm4wYLi88pTMGgKZQe34Fn4ujxOjaVqyxga0Nl5ej0qlQTsTblTqSOCT/izk5PfVt/KDRZPd32zAFS9dszi5s5O/epTA4yail6epIyKXtwqj/G5uRY3Z5Z7hj9c1jeLpfpouZ7TG0tLhU@dHfnHVUJ9I0ksPp4JCqsshYzgGi7UUQAPLRSDby4nYfigIkpGZgoeiI4TcLTGRUmnN4vptJouQ9wlGXguWE5zdFi0QcnIoBuhZLaLEN2zhiNoowvlm5mUvYsSMNrDRU6UQonJG2BJgTeeMj/v8wT659nSSnN9p/pPZj7/3T@Z95nvix@Jm4YbupS6kVp4ntzatpS6lm6ub3aqQYpfscnEyAR9YPaIsU5mWVpOY9bTq8lOX61S6xzXggHd2q6Uyq26a25qeXlZSu2cVuVV@VA7D6dvqnmaITzDCUScY9POzneWMr/V3E5Oqz7hE71VMLJZXvIs3PPTwuu7@BTL1joWRYf5qcxv@YFEpArglMo4Ji6nUE@YPXeESx12zniGdr5L0RQMO7pujxxa9Fl6iYazYpS4lVJvQGX97pXdu95azVVprZICMnZzQ3JhHtJiBCnluMIJjISOzBCqrAJ29roseiMWG5xsv9t8t/Xu5evD14f77EmhtFXaQr6fgZRk9bSehkJ8Ag2yfbwnpQaf3HX9O@fLcqo0SK@upVdjxXZWSQUyrqDoK/W63mD11UajDsKG9MJ7pVJ8rK9vZdZK@iZTU1XcmVXcRHajC5RBbjXVSHEka5squGlMvainqnnhrW/qasrP8TeIsp7ypdTWy/c4BhNcM2UXyZWnLRTLNzs38F@9YfWdnRvqS90IB/7c3PBw@Kd8hG/8EX1igHGYKPy3EzrtPNX4LrfD/3fwZ/eQ51TeWJfV1PtKFUTh3fm785SU2mZykUovkxedIqhJHTTCVhz6s/wV/92KvxJ5rIBVuRK@wevOCluv6oxZK/l8/kz9UREstO3tja2NlPQb4NgtS7whNFzz2LagswKKfc6ix5pnvzRwQagTLnwEx8vRR7xS4ElwmVhgzDG05nBVL5pzcT9h4cW86A6@pN/Ez@MWNPSVJHTZdAcla5MIovoe0lYitoIHWeBOW1W6lh4ArpE5pN1r8ANq/QFuo8JXJYDLskf@UMUBtYIqPXggFLA/1PzhOSLHSMIzp5claC2APUar5TO61ANnUvn2XAM3JbkDfuRTb8J4JJ/uXeCWKe2sxXRjBK@wNqcCcrPCKEWiHDPHk3/AwZqjNpKyf/BiD@JA37pNyw9FbNlr4pU3lL2ltsrCdgR4gPc@VASnCBwBAR14csND7eMeYJOqM8swHcPbtIwRoLJMzxIlWdYWEev42oDoiL4NWs0HxDx1heeArZyLZEUeBD2UCWAh5o6aQ7qRweuYWVF6eBxyvaGy62CnoYKhbIcVo62QAhcUBr@mkiKa/Za4vqMSsZmw6Y0sFG2Z71hTQjjhEzHqRloZZvtlXlSDsvSVYoJ95HpK@bv@o0fmu0G93yir/coQn5lMH5roC8XmICvDSr8C4jGo243ysJ7J2I1KX/1KwXe8JQfbc2Hl@arIG@TcqQAtuCzUV7Mf607uO6eR3a87GSB5lF35ceVj1qgU0D7L2hU928t@C4YOzwekOax8zDhlYwe@uJQ3sRsQrJKMUU54YZQLpVf5WDcaaPD1IGImsw@ZATr9ei@TaaiQeA8CZyOWe48eGZledVzu5XIqQr1bfbxfH4Kjkange0kxdsaPP9ZHEL@kwLMCyfRUIB7iCV7fhLQDfWXgMS/TiHROI9mjYyCvX6ms/Pjxyo9XKktLH@vjXL@R5ewvFSJpQOLHSHw5tttSWfmxyqZYQjPLivzQLj3UVnwmZ@1MBpicHcRicgpXfgwhg0wmoPoG9SVdnhcsE0cJEzsE@RUQdNA67fqgmzp8uv2HbvhAdVHzTdsW4HyT@8C2WniMre1n6WocgyAwTNzmiYFn48ePpSBpsSkNUkbl0rSYgSMMdKcbXn1C2/8ZP7flLv06Tw0HOjfsWdM1LdCHX92IVVdSTVThfM@sIwiqgevCTZlrLL4VEZQNaQ@AIe2BcDnUIsgkoScEZEUEQmkFBQSxUE@0@ZlDdOwK6ie0rcOaDyqEkwGVeQ4ZdvZDhXQTyJMNLmbvUHrggKoiPYBMIA2YB7vBqqDI2KNHTLzuVJhe3MS2AMEQ7kNGR6AZSiHxe1AKOJDKDyCjqA8pEaDtAYbgVttEQmu/W0Jip7wCETIfsnzDvEYb5pWR4/NzIpBvKicDy@LBgw@ZypogCP6pawLxIezmNynR3JfY7uHLo9ene8cvayfwC13SrfjtV8HNkjP3yg3wvrim7dB2UdM41q1vvjQZU7BLhqem48WxLfbl6xesWHz1LItnngLrU3yMHBrUUojJ8ulOCV9zvU7@yr6w88kbsPGOT9qZSvdt54JrspAcapx70ekV0eEVPg7vQWMuDmpMXCHUt3xfXJeXC64eplOy6ByPPh5HAbVQXK9Hm36CfQu0SwZXUmRp75Vnd2y6T7bLESTi0zU7Qx6d6oeE1@JR1xgkWtreKhRKrJBFhx44ioFjNXCsBY71wLERODYDx1bg2BYOPcCsc8zQfV5d3Yicm5FzK3Juh861QuSMMKwVI@dq5FyLnOuRM0ptLUxtY4vwslTATaq6lodh@tpWEEajDkPyXAc0@rTnGhBanIGE6GsznpDeVtJzc7sgEjrIHyJQsbgRvYP2CWArCqcqy@nI8pT5m/CEtkri3TwS2D3PA620N8Z7QEHo1BLD3fiShOcqmT3LAGPAGoKVUtkH@bfUEj@lxpuUoh35iKGih@8QHS9hgjg6XWXLxWdOcHFeMMdWnIuNHwLEQsbEjjMQRHIqS4mWlmNcS/jFsS6hgkWOLoAocggsg@T5B0Gap95obpKrtyeZQDg3yRmiON71ebGQNwohrwRRqf0nbJUgPW6nWFTaYAaIi8tJBqYKFI8rqlzrJfnX3//i/2C//v5nv2I//Pmv/t//9D@j@9/jz38Am4UVQ4Cf/ozRkhD4@VeMFoDQYpQoEsGvluQffvFLeP2f/i374Sc/40F/8hdydi1EBCHoFcX8@T/Dnz/An/9Tzq6HgD//Iw6IUeTsjZQwrRSA@ulfMwapIZYQ2S/@kjE5AwaGIiSvzut4I3a4CUcQsqFOrsZ0OP/F6x@BxwU1IwNe8aZHbxksADWG3DPwJu6o7oE5w0c2UUubhtnFAyyEl@uj/WOiCeP6Wgfk7aoFRo8YkkhD7n@flVg6gzA4sIKnNFW4Dhf5F/mWo1CEzch5oA4vUBOo6HLMkBLo3kog39QTmPgadluoR6pzGRH8fWVBMxE0IHIgWXRXoCTSCmLjkIy4N5kujwy6uii02AzxU47ozkRJnLCgxxJMqJupYoNUpn2gyxidexKPSh5WfwBFAtFCfiNj8YW4kJ1GF5WcqDZ7h/tTFQY/TTAxL@IaKUyowmT5DljktIBX0eJaTcJzegVAvVBabSROUZkHLH/99deyFPMroAx5LYUwxDLFVUYYpCeDirGgYiwIaOY4SdesF4tTNFDDgXoxeWIQjxZTUclokXBhzQnKAcmAviAfEM22eyO/W5lFTRo5qexmkcdQ6o2KqCdnDumcKpPVmQiAMxmnMl2W81EXZmBmC2p@TOR2widRWosxJeLEKgVxT5rmUlhy@va8kksmeAtqvZG5Z0LFwu@YUO6eCW2s353QdLFi3AT6xfy9W@0EaiLU8BEyXvFTiQYKm8ZfgOhF6ggp9sipqNDlqYkuT/PKZcqcC7LBPx8ccp64FduLHX2OnZhX7pDPhLEnAxe6HC5awUFXyXDYawGe6Hbwa0s7jutZfvx0JHGTqZPG87lMt@NAq5bFw9ZtceU7rjfg5zQm25WwZRNWKB5nC10fRM0ZhZbn@bnt2MPzczA@e201YiC@aiZu6k9LJkQEVyy@Epq2hwPFxUsjhurdOMne5dFObfNCORyIwDQkUmPQoTOtHnS@WBcv/w1ucsUs8uuAwSJtDhU62LXr9t2O5bh4NBnGnkJ/EOFGgozBgGjJMiPLzBhFohOtmFlDFVG/@uyo7KsiXl8dxC8mESSYkWXeNI@Rs96c5M4XJsejBemdfD69J3F6T26nt217/nCaZvLE0R58fl7Sq0qEAQAjMlbvJiMrTiOcISdBSuiNF8/zCPcmsUXLoVpIaQ1AawJca4N8ZMM3n7bvC8LfLOL/7QUYRN@7b/GRMXsyAX3Tp3uiqYvmB3PwCoAfqGq0xDGWXCjaz@6ZlujoUA8vy2RSXA6eDQEVczCwnOii3gDxHTKPC6Fm5J5WR1V44ByavMssuyguLqJn5y2rZ0ysliIgszG8QY6PLaNF@up@GUdFR0oP@gA0kFnI6glTjM7wIaDSApExspequlisOIgdSg9NxhGFB4v5RwN306oZB0ErfA7E9UCDpuiYTzpcdTAZTPi5Xz06kC/Qo7z94SX5Co9Du5MhwAd@AbWejZJVb1Ofx0qYpXu0CCGslswynZ4RNFsuWOMzZfh5LLo7pzTKEEaqBKWcsE4Wlbh9W4nHpCKQSW6V3E8k7xK6e8tcTNQ4skiF7X5eEzKDedfo9UxTiWPkPreWmOvM6AT0wxJznQWtyvkchRrGJE03xEsuK9y@UCUbnAfwvITnG3giQuiDnnOBCvKGdm0w5EUhfWMQs1qET91EWzTGRTU@jxiDkgI3DuTehGmaC9M0Z9I0E2mGNSCZZAxIMhNJilLA4rmtCHpWe7hAO2MQ9tzhcZvaho/jGh7OvV6n7XTJzrL0ZboECjltpUt7CijldCtdekYOP106IcdFuvQVOKK6lf6ULgXVAgE8eCXHE/QXKhzfzXRpV1FvpCGecRykq6VLYZkCzGP@Shy54cOrTTHr74ajqpaV5UZllqHE@PBwMVv1Rpa@BfgnUHF2NgQuVVhxhYCxA5JoNGItBk8Hmg2t515ZnjKv@SgFQ1NifCMaQ4HwTCU2qIJSMiJ9lE6lk8qIE4ahNPgITyAQ9WZpPkVMn@mZ3UWOSB0klAo5mT5xTyN7oKVQeB2A44M4vSh@UF5JFLwA70cnRl5E5ww5QXJEES4GUOeQhUx9n74lU1jWU@cw89KPl9DsGAEWYi4A4aVEaGM6HWw4tE0psYE7SAoJheJsnx2Pgx9RKVF6p6KRVhA1c0EweYucoWKIV371tuzE4iFpCRWEgfVCg9eysF0gXYxBka6LWaq88gEJMZ3TooMRLRTbZ8JJcFzdZKmtWNQMBXF5kqS5kmoSImt4CsLIGPLUo3kZPBvh87qvQcwxXiehIIJYzDAVrl/dz7DfXW6/BwZ1wISpBOYZ1vOb0lnz@tZWdoryXpTsbAFiYJY9U@caR2EKEcuhdxCzzG@TtRkTH@9D50Y@TzTEPmXtB2wL@wR38G26b8FxoZXgXSY9L3Bg9qK4mFGzFknvUguMFg1TEnh4xkNKo6zdTivP@LwixhBso@Hx2QXsJQs4XniIjzLgTbGc13Jv5NDyqqhu0/F20cwFn3VwcZVYeKp4zBPUPa1fC5dogcfh@fGzw1cvvoFGd3NzU52disBaC3Gjdly6dZog7LYUs3gwLG6lo7UTXdcbLp058uySMvIAY8CgeRsufqKOq0KXxfT5VN2FeBw2xlGB6yKqBkZCK6GpY2CTbQu@8kv4lBVDIAnMW@B3lnprOGuE0oETOufn1Hydn@PinPNz0Yph0YTTSL9JMXEoYrReA1yJ1Uxkcfkzpy/iAMCoT3ulggE4ca4iX4eSAjwHwyB2GGvkDO1gsQOOD9EmymAuX1nVcXTioB36EB24KEMprmEXtriOh8rwWAiNA5@0tFKks8QNHbxexB@4Dh0QT4fuktmOl534wdArkT1yrgxaBsJTobNwYhTxBVnBvJjr8Js/fB4Xd2vSEHLAmyyzOhrN@BS3octxYQ/4ueHh0g9fpUhEMK3RAh43e1YfSDoB2Z0zmvzShlLp7tudDghSXtwsyRe4nBoQNee2c7vBeZgp9sbo2a3gZgaxJoxuRRHjwMBOJXGgqc@KG2BNbWeBs9EXGIvLZBgeWlqgRVoEBd9NeGxy51Y2FndJmajJpx58VMS3pJxjyfIt8raHt0heGk6Mz/T5FB@aFpOWpAdiM5fBEZqSOEu5QvOUGq5RGyhySg7O1kQnXzZh9MzgqE8FD5ktSQ8cUjy4AoyZfG0NGLgOGm00vaaGS1Id9pCtFiW6D8alwWWeLODgM3sJ7BAGUZFYvrpPKBj5YUt@iJOJ0oMU6kIuaxg/EGV00x0NkSyzJYGOT6hgVeZVIHhZj72sQlfjwZyElxQ5A1gysionMAG8mP14wDXvbFRQiqAePncptuV5DoFJl6BKGF0JLpYRl29Z2Esre3H5YGJdL3am4gs122L9Gr9GLyu/xhVYJZ4ItR0aHp2Mqrs8rbtzerBckx64Tpqt0CbkdqKhkT2MHJKxZDu3EUAtCkko6hla/vXQL8EXaMgGKIFNtGJBId6od9JGHMF11HigRaFRjjUpih6nBgls@6BQ2sDPrPwQV60@gojUxEJ7p84zmwrlRHwgzh84tJJbzmkyRRWrjhFTEgUvTfQP175KtOA9UFy3XAZh5PWtwsY2rZ9mTnaY7de3G9kVsyIza2gbTt8feVeti47bvQRjgQ0@NMfm5OO3jK2vMdxgUnzEN@3rG5U87cvfpIMttgu0uSM4VoOOfjiTGaN9wHhIR5qxcMNReQl368Mniz8luTwjpWylH0ghX0Tdr280Kk6lUO7XnUbZyWTUYaYyzOgZBT0e6WoZNC0fdqkPG7QqMr/CXgZLF/GoZBxbddvsyHXMrpv2GV3GG5/To31kQQXqG4N4fbqEXofrxX3aKE9GP1ERZ73oHrupmLYbwA0nAwtVY7jqs4c3mePPg9HGWnk2HHP44AEuUS4L2zSegWtpMGr2bBN0EPETTQxcrlgqiUX3JkO5BQWFfjb35LRAC6RgcDkINd3BRES2Och5kJedGMqqgm2Xmr0PZADVBJk8x4stPADjIJy9CXAGqKnpUTlV6H5hOWE7g/sk1DKuImdLQViwowLhUW5oX8M5mH@0CwIeO0yA0hpjpooVveRbt3FRAZlq1TQPevBh1B9Q@65xegVH8Nau84Fhe2FMzR/h9YEK05EZdkA0lgA6bnBf3iUYlvGiCcoCBxZochvzg/iO6Oh1INg08E5T0I04uYP4Wi7FecCvhVOgEeQDV5wMEZeyoYqiBsbhsWvpQbrEaJyhDF7U5JRjoR8gFPO6ILgPwX1j2F0Q3EXcI39RsAfBeFncgmAbgvmak/nhLoRzS2oBwBBH0UBcz4fu@dCwewpfMI1LrW@4wlZYJhMwNhQBxguGl0cyPhNLz9kSLx0ubAnxgvpJYsUBUKQVUXnwPZIWCsXDORQuF7E0OU/YNbszMTH4BCw@p5RA7WL66koCP4sRAPUPVCmbDQ8S56UdZjQhPxo0Ox0sbWDWKvv06TbKhCAm5U9vBNLHSwjHOWM55NyK8PC7rKJy5ZE@ikjz44il@XHtFtigUT6CSlmMVAivW1G9bttgL0JUFa2cyBu7lCp7HPnU/QYrhdoj4iOvFnfzsTgjPdjjpBqZZc3Iad6fqwbKPcQ0oEVuRsoC92EZ5Rl2@iF0LgldBeiQm1NyZiZkRtTSz83s/XKTAvqoUhNvylzRmmAaVgWBc8gzeLnGdQJHtpwucX@8ectOIrMXIOP7Fc8BwXAHaMCWLVDjQZtoOxpf8wN6vlBcy9IQPge5idgUKKv78OkfoHIh40STPcLLSJIqic1hzQx4mG/kV3W6yk1lj2v6@Zmr80Vj6cdppJHNyhNJ3WNoJUuswMKNMWV2c7ce@u04cx0VX8Le8ZXFuiIo9EAS7yOCNwsYfaeQJbNQbLAEx5EE0gx3NEm0yXN@oxRNXZwHPsGwFq/bCy0wpKqcDEeaOcIgAAzleKyssLmqkeoUu1vPh4Fxk42sMLwDjEsFmOxlKa7OsTu3T4133DfcmkMciYfgSkG0ML2AMrsd2LZgBgfxNPMci5kzGfkJdbrjui0lMJiEwUAYghXQAJTl24VCs4qbl1HykJwwellHrKIO2t0y@CwJL2pXwAONTyGbSMRKh6pNGatNzL6xfbqijsKxNYKkgtkdHAzi2oeVpv0ROjSBHsyNFGh83PNFO4OFnqeWOKEe5F3DwYE3OjqMutY7MvqHBYEwVehoR/uHqQxu5owy8D3SYvfwdbzrYpdtDW3isNCDUSa1HFKzsyNjMtHhG79JLeVHvke3slvOJRjVzYmUYpbD7@oo4UW/uS0ciMV7eoU2oXFvGuQBMYGSwtQ0x7pSxF2@uEtbViW@548GhXQJT4igcfmeddkCq5@viB@4/ph@J9BZKGijwdClEJEQ7Q1kn@xP0X71As3Sih6DIGeH8EQwCs7fcN8JH4vK6dxA0vH0CzWGoo4xSeHKZ7KM5YeEivG6ekPyNcswu0gEyt4n3p2C4iJJvpH8oOhxLxuyAicHwdnjq3gHNDaHSZB14k/oHbKP7zo6uA8NIaLci36KRAOuGNJz3QEKOQ61YfwdYABn/IOT02d7x8eaODCZzwjgLAIfJ8YlGLQhUNzDLYZJcTYAt2PyQnmAmUXcPL1KhJz0L/EIkxVswqpwhezkvML9njwHOZ3eZrIRwqscnFhC08nizUdeFsSq6QHYUci7KJoSi5YLogXAMVY8uJMbhmniQtuXVt8FinfpDnqd8@JBxA50IkeC9DNh@n4d02yExPPw3Ex4LhGu8XBOVASlmV0vAirFgeTUdQR3w@QILDuTVoVBpg9e0e4dzfVidJdvg/U16KTZEXA1LEoulWHATiIgFwt5N6f0echSIk4o4GF4nYcL@S6Kkg@pTMA@SaaPT0kUkEVrXMWSkCkp1Ry7x@@Gj0JIwzLctsKjY3mT2PFKKQZEhDrJgZrAi7Kx2lYrEZaMHmgcqjNydeeJrIkhqcfKNBkqv056umLNqSMxLlGaGWLcmFoSSIeCl2IoCCcKGgtqbjWIPBGRJzG0CLUUJCsFO7GTFRyyNl3FKzhs/gl/gsqeJC6AS80PfMApH/PM85msJINI6S7J89mU1CZDb2RxT5GpW1qRKO3JNMb5SuKViz1Qs0v3oQdpWny@re2OnNZSqCfiiiLQFDN8D0MEpyMAPRDfRUWIgTfSb/Ir0hdGH6zCnjVmNbSpDTozSUpMZuIN5j6eQoanXTJ/NBj0bLFvjl3RdJk4Uai4jpM9EcaY0aBJB7gAh8Nn0SUmHyGSxg4R8xWu44gCfLzTnu5CZnjZIqjWtg0oh5pUcyb8mmbcZlbkU4oWG@E@eVTAPej2xYjgJcdrT3j1tSYFE7c8q21ev50hmECQcZf2lOJW9pIk/Whkmxe7X7BiobCpF1b1GMuCoeqCtrpGtz0HJlIQUCzohcK6viZJu@5gwpeOKKaKuNZyiDDLXmBD/wZk07rEyxClGrQYBIgHZPqWd2m1NEk6tlo0BtwcEUdQlEe@xU@poH306AO2FZ4nhPeF@1l@KThIGD6xfeZnA5i0cDkr4RztwPL69pDP5LqXdgsZGMxLt91ez72igWicEub8wEh9awhMWVFZkiTa9y9oIduFtuMDNwxxZ7PRdC/pnA7BBrBTbTzeiCZYJdykihjiifELX2OUQHpmz7D7KE5zCMBdLBEHAgIga62Rad1Kg0REfCYNwWXULdcc4ckHRlAyedB@LtUVqO6WZ4P2jRhMpULRYrRDAZ8@PzhhJ4f7p29rx3sM3EfHh28Onu09Y0@/YafP99ju4dE3dBwse374ArTLCau9ega@r06PD56@Pj0ED7l2AjFlCpBqr75he18fHe@dnLDDY3bw8ujFAWAD9Me1V6cHeydZdvBq98VraKy/yDLAwF4dnrIXBy8PTgHs9DBLqQbRpCgeO9xnL/eOd5/Da@3pwYuD028oxf2D01eY2D6kVmNHtePTg93XL2rH7Oj18dHhyR7DjEnPDk52X9QOXu490yB9SJPtvdl7dcpOntdevJjK6OHbV3vHSHwil0/3gMra0xd7lBLl89nB8d7uKWYocu0C84DAF1l2crS3e4COva/3IDu142@yAunJ3o9eAxAEsme1l7UvIHOScgdXoFx2Xx/vvUSigRMnr5@enB6cvj7dY18cHj4jXp/sHb852N07KTPpxeEJMez1yV6W4RUwlDTgAG5BOLifvj45IL4dvDqFNuP10enB4SsVCvktMAaorEHUZ8Tgw1c8t8Ckw@NvECvygQogy94@3wP/Y@QpcauGXDgBru2exsEgQWDiaTyb7NXeFy8Ovth7tbuHwYeI5u3ByZ4KBXZwggCAE9N9W4NEX1OusZyALu4EYZUCyc1ScbKDfVZ79uYAKRfQIAEnB0JaiG27zwXPoS7npblTbrdO4M3O8omhkNsP4dk9fLYHFh8/l0@O/F9Do7OVnLxLhEFDEwbCq5gFpbbqvGU1R51z22m72DUPo/EZ7L7fyeLplire2XMm3XbNHJ8opwip1Pn5m9o59HNPzs/V7H1iJsi4K4bY5X4blCry2HONFnXzE2NLcUZVH4mzdLL8YIv4WMujcPBBZfl8yxLRcHEIIg6GicShT4CshZqRVo0YDoslSVPMybEiOpFserAomN50ffhxPkUvvG2IeYBy5usW8nnswxIZeLIcC@mHROjQNXHyGq0DsNuUpOZb1kVHKcSTwy6/GKBSgzgEO4RuYEdR74jetDpT0XPT8YlYXMtDxkpw3E5wDA6/JRvfBMuYKBfNo5wpfGiPHmpADSUERqHKk6KFQmL1ifKIR8f923ysUC2HR7XQcWsva18fvMXOXKG4Vp7yfx7687qFq/rw7EBo7@oUr0GP5w0OABXMxu4XsMSe8CnVfD4WB6wysidDYDwLqItAV3YL2lRsqrsWNet4AhE/jiEeHxpjzx7HqQc1/MVx7eXT1/v7oDmR2rWt9c2NsiRONPKGX2f58xtMh47hRe6CFX1lg5lGQbFasgt2z/7MYYSx0xOx9BAQjywPCo088ZbwcGcytxH4@WV8GAiz6@MJTg4eYibjIUyezHD9o7UkBfI6t2YKAVASWVUxN31jTBa@AaYSyYDJdyH3JlRqY/xB3GH1D6p4mCEhQELErP5gOAHJhc4F6T15P1jQSX0bWraFIJocyPHACNYgccagzqRVrrjGkd6EbMdKEexaLGisr1TsFBOIWJqmIjgEj460hCSOXD@owdzTBp@vhbyB8xtx@CIG4VFateEJsHE/jJkLDkfkY86iYgjMjWoFiujRozClHYYDqaogio//J4/mi9cGIoUvaGBTiIOVRyGfwxAahH6SVtk1l1Q8NQXxlIXEineQ3HnZEVjKwZEz4j04oY9xXNGBfeR1FaYhBSDfBCAhOxNs@p34Qfj/G/JkDv4d6HAC9ohbpIdtZ2Tdk5OElfMKeq/EFPsqWDEWW6YWcTPu9U2E5iZeMN0wY2IZ3phPLAELROlMAo9v@JGtyhwGoJDjuEa8/uIBCVSJuwb0nJ5Q3X3AZ/o9x@wPlODA06CpmMHbyJLNlQ2WyOGLyqfwCyyW3As8v@4J7aMlnYEdLtBizQl76MscR0YnnYOZzq/QoEdYy0k0kQ16UMMjcSqIqhVU/rFYYRS1Mq0g9AZM0cWHqYbTIXhmY0LhBzMggQKhtU/xDAu2QZpVJHRuvnElPY3yM9GK4ynkoAKpXWantPzZN9rUZ8amSKxVxkXRmCTiedgSZ2I2reEVNhc9jp3WaEfYmPKQloljImIsMjQjAuWrasB1amSvQuppmBLlNaT@tXPh4G0dFh/iCiC0xAmb8S3uGntp0GGbvfvlW44SzyBbq8n0Dxxat27y@UocmqOeO6SCPf2HfsQRsDiv0LqEdijikmFeoKccyKh9lbPH8KC0ciLnwZmR0GegE4HnGf03CzsEKCtTa2CZfOaEg0gl3pBVHgbmC7p43Q1d36BLjDNXIFNAHPjggllhBiHJaDfhIs3Z2kb0JbYt4OLTElhOV1da0xj1Dadt9O3ehFadfnC7Tt53Rv5AG0zwAtLkaCAetIJL0IH2ocXe2k7LvfLZU6gOOJB08ur1yVFy4C828rXLR74Y@xLSYE8pZWkGfRv3pPhuewhFY5XZRFzy5EXDPTROKEZaaFhrgh648ccjAYJ0@6Fl/MWr1@wLy7E8sAePaM0le2GblgPqA4wpWoXpd7mmQfB9TP1EpM720XahkZ0ys2wa1AnH9iSRgMCWRdFSoCoCwZ44thrH5icg6rExQW02w1G@WsGgUtcdiN0WOGiKxiYf4myPelkJz8Z@e3D6HDvjvGNOYzPQrAVjfTiWyE2nPh@shcx4hjOcAFOk6cEbIPuusRuN0WYLwCgtZid16vp4yU8Lh/16PmQVb@gSWoBaEKiqln2Jh/HSMNx9yojW2Yphs4hvZbF/NcuPBw5UR6L0pKj0sngmu5Zl69vs1ELZZUc9w4QeFjsZYfTVVbADn7r@EEFf1hgrFHVdz@mrOET7@qSmUUXAb3BCqyQdvDw6PD4FRoojiALBCNtMZD4dispXYwE7cng0KuT@PSrkAB40ZvE9MQ9N8OCcBLnMZyzkkgxlbxo43As59JPmMA3J4pC869HBrLjbBkQoUR0hVf8KlS@fGqGUYtizdDSsONyVNy0hnbRbkiK8R9p6IFc9nA99T5HJDxSANSY/iOVRz6AljhWCMulb/ZB6exi07gYHkKbPlA0ZxsdSQTjS2TRaScA9NY6nZeEaCR9PZ@r7l6YHusW4BJHDJSzBliOQGdJNapgbo2n3bKgDQJfZdbHB4eoqKAgagoifOCtRiYdnGWKDRLTMOQ0KalfL7YegnCpJCjfbCf@BPzFdlupANxt7Wv7Aslp0EtVowI9awnANankPWg6@Da8UncEkpQq0btIDZYNH3oHuG/Vwbz7upWzyMpeC3IBUBds3T7vYreeIIEcnQ6qkeCKuMqeHnWU4z6tSsRsgEBhXRUYs2EgJKAZZnJQCqqC8SSDIReKSxe0@PSrv6X2WGJEOe/QHyQDExWd1rWRAgB7zLpwzAFxIKyEBU1s4A2L4PiTuToyBJV8wv7juFDelKTyPkLmJGjJz38YjyvnYgMs6Lv4isBZwjM8RWjRHOLMxFK/j1AHfNKQ@CwlQ4QFtMcjiHJy5uThX5@PMCZxisvLAuaQNcRiLxILngp@24YJ@REZE2f/CDVQvbdvruXyCKcx9p@c28VxM0BSQGj4m2ahg497UA0swOh7KN2kmz/PcCbIkSBd7mwLbhe1A/bCqbCcYsaieObygRECF1yXaE8ao7aLqRE78ETWKnHLicFC0OqZOB0XyuC/obkQrC5TCRy6xqGbiSpw4vEg5GaWfiKJPRRHEJaM0E1GKUrQTfKp0MQaqfnwmcxbYJbQqiUqAVcICKkh9Y8x7NwXa4EfDNHgkd2LHYbEhBAQB6yYL9wwieEOKjsBITNvzNIJXWoJHK77lZZmOFC0kz5MaB0v3SA0QVCJ8QsesOIrIkCrYQC/h8RpqQIzI1w5FcWKaKswwD5AS2fZwr5YST0UtsdTA4LOGCOVjwxZPuk48wFl6Gf5WmCISyMWJ5UB4bIFQhcB4OtqiDl1ZXiyBHixIUctMbzEFByUocf1NS8Z4M6AoiXoVaO4QJ3fO6G5Ahf4cHaUk8f3VPth13BdblJhqOEGDD4@JF0aeNYbuGc0xEwpqf8IRa@HJz4wItYcgvh6l3AhajWQuFkJPNyXzYGKtSsiF24ADZod8Wgi8uLUh1uEYAuo7Dh5j3QscJBasC5rgtM9ZRlaKPaTN5K5pcw2VZFtM6fK42TkKOFnkAXHZqVxJsaNiRA6nmxEp0XImhESJveE1OOwhPyiYI1KlRCzk/6ICx@WO8Yq9EE7ncKLYF0lEiCso99vEIgQOyv02seDAsWK/XSyCs6JD1lL8ablIlARnAS5KFD0GGlOK66AgYByHGk9BEUGTRvysGKunzKE2plXFWKc0YyqFLBJHwyXToMeYF4y4fSwpjsC8elgajSi30MaZF1YrPPFC5D7sIlXlZJPAS3P6oCfMdJAClVFDxStJwgigsfkgmOgz9/naTToxKM07LNQHxVNRO93k7t4E2qBVKaizBmVwOlJE/M5c4nOzp1RFXazS7P074eoyQTUueHK9FkLL0pwZX@kOqjIxqpK5i5VQksULMOXuhSl3D0z5GCZRsVehvSRnysNzgK27UJydzeKgxzvoSAkcoGlbNg5iYz/4ypjchXMJjK0Urakz@KqyMEJkJ9@F4/E0Djp3vRvOxgnProGjbh8tz50@9WwhZ5OyMoeikKrULFlZJIu0NvV3BVxgKlHfVrtodu2wJ5C6u6T5OREiMi4l7oaTQKnkqUUhsqj@6wv4l40Va7I@cMITwzBgLUufWR00ZAQfYeJbxcIIMUWW7IeKgCQjbg@dVn7UW50@XQIPlF8YTb0zJ0/4gE9s0EmHrHGNlZC4oAsXKaegtQr027zu2Z3pp@amP3AHYOO05xJA8H0cx@eDUlMqPTJNp7rW92rL5rZns/mK221TZ7/dv5I/msl6EbKOG9OhUjvWlWj9b8Ms8hKUwG9hydcDGVlA5MO5ROJEuyEGt5gz6jctT7pPVecxNHzwPtJiyZWkVIrVTOgyi5OH6AYoOh7ZEkmiGYyC4LPRAOdrfL64Eys3jpFZXICnYfEaeYLWZEyCxmj7luGIo4hEg9nxcP4ihM3i8ei4uYtSsB0TGO1bseHP9/zOj5YlQnBF8i1sLc8ve5RquuaeU5GNUhJkcVtTmST7tNx3gYETWjUEVZo2VALZwcnQFW6ZC3sJDHN1/hDYfayn2wwiEOJFSYoO7xTq22W0tJiZo0HIyrBo7sHKeeZWOMp9D3Nrcl9z678BJ6cLVIq5hfUgGtjSnUptupNPF94GB1/35xzd8uZ0fz9x4ElzEvQK@pa3XigU8BCcmdvtcIICZ4ltN5@EzuOYeH5w9aX3ppnHqMn77OZeZ4c0AChC49QEyglOTYygvYkdp4XjOQ7uyvngc0h@Ak@L0TJOO1zc/uaUhI9QIvOsEnuPGcT8vWfBddNgOPIug8ASrDeD2GiGXsrBMjlgD3q08USdcEkaIaN@s9i1gBMfleq19EBc8UjjfHgdj3odbUOUn1u9nptlb12v11qS@e7QZIT9/XiEAgfBpYS88vh0PUSWWZd2L3ZFBoLELnLndyzh/bl89JP2MnnWAGfSFGzHjq3O3nigyPV3MggmZDmD2cwwuYHbezoyNFEyTaHfjZYfSAZk3wu6bwwUk/g0DQxtoNhLFbmAolW8RJOvDsbxlF3IMi7mUBIgKj8XhvPsbmhk6nxytQ@u7SiQdQyWcLscbf2m4qWcLAAPmSufjfU28rDAcQia8AjE@8W4KeOhU7/9B0e3ceQANzfSGG@4JTZ23lg8H8FgPNYsdjlst6F68ZH4anDUWICOVGVOp1UKyBpRsJ717QjsGSXd9tP8ADtcanMyccwEIfViI8vSo2F7Kw0Yfqc8SkENFNUP@InLJr7KQbXeH9E9KZE@o2E4XEAxq3cwwjlGkKSHZuXbK6VWq7HlQSbDarWn4MjlWO1pjT1Dj6dP2TN4f4rvjyrF9fUyXzn3TL0Gz6eB5w17CjioCcI72Z7BK4TRVUvYlcIiXs5XlrPl5fPKTrXs5@u1p418vgOuv/v9n/zdP/2TfE28fI8vT@ml/i4E0jQtv2xeLz@6KeN7/VkjvdysLw8a6U4ZpQzV/WvPN3pGbJuYZv6D3Isb7Jw3VQYWrVqppFn60yfuOhtGTi9y4iUGUXSjN@gaFJ0RhmolXUs/egSunUr6x2kVT@4Q/kbo/xH8mYq6nOaLibU0fVw72T04iN8TFN4/2kZLEyfcDbE4zXZ8GzL1PhXMnufqTNNYI8feh@Thgu5zDpgkkaVxxSgn5jtBZJA7Wn1Pq1QpYb78lBYY8XVPfDVa3@/Q8qJggRKF0WIwjPSwVeJL5whHBhQewpf5plSFVzfMPpCLa90qubq@sd7IpVIpSplW556bpOYotUF0VbEZWyxLK934iXoDqDKQd8SGJNcZIERmpFIPTaDjkSnOcXDobkjMMJ1XmE6lY0djMCDJ4rcKPgiv4mVkbYidZdjCEnXQmI9ouzXaBpP7LtwDAsIb0Nk1o9t5ZX7p7CR2GWDsImA88WT6lvjwlN3onni6Jj5AaE6dxDCNkDMPevckQRWRx@AdzI1ZoXovbutha8HMkthx7/YmnR5enkmbJvwr0E7AeVUUVs8JTkXEFHjMptXGiU9eo3mBRZv2yDC0cC@sY@LsApgFTg8P0eUGX3BtMliQUB/QwhHncLRxz7fSc/hWAbcNThWvuA@uhyYxzNDhTlygcFKNjojh8QM9sDIA23XAIZGr8B4tsyXxwEXeYoHGg9kFlwNVxKQJPSFpgzqu6NMbwWH@qqhJMtWVcMkOWJV97ILioAgwBSE1OnEWVMOEve857@ddG02rFClJnsz/19619LZxxOCz9SvWEhpLWzmSkqJJmjaAc8uhLZD2JhfWWl47AhRpoV03MQL995IfyXmsJn4hTZMihwSytPMgh0N@5HI4jyQTmTSWG2ahL14xnBz67Q6EGq5PuyoaZW@1ruuFJqroMiELR04Jb6jX44OODKbSEl6snVduR4X0mSiV70nOOQ4mNUdodCJSpSB6kJM3OfNQ8uJ6UT4ubldnlXtaNou5HJWS0fdNF1coB8LfSt2Ujw5EzoOkg9oCY4TjTE@haiYoltr3Az7xqWTe/28c9C7AM0sxkvla1ZZq6oTDrc6xZ5Lv0UkCOoiZonNEcEo5uBcJ5rK8WDRRm6EcutbzpULF1ljPm3yGjMeAuy3Ocm6Q3WztVMJM@W1J2Kx47TdStE8luzote0YMWzXJxXIthSQUzni6Kx9OH9l0wlnTDib28fYdxisE48q2blGLHMuaeFHN/CpcOwI61ymKvshxkh8dqLZo8@Rwyvf7trhB6rS1DbwWHkfdBwLMwh1acuioFntluQQS7Chvkxeb6TZxX/2/OW60lKcbLjVLm4@eYjkgG@2TyU/pidXcoxvXZXIHvisNqLP6XeD80uZySchfktTVooRXwvtB3TxaQxnpusKHQEqVFSybHoRr2Wpq9PrWf8WtDw@kdsMHq@DQD5BONdDCDvrrnhhzsqbWr5Rm6I/tz63VkNASDC4z3VZHWQ7zWpwzezjXnbW5X5xtSjTMhzctbzQrsuDUmLBz9IXaQ/pcmO@fYNIWIZyjy2b9qvn0mB6xO8xmce6@xLXzhAsKgsEKEYrBSD/RxymusP5EbgHrgQUpAjmpUtQlfe50BHmoh9n9tb54uX7fHw@Pu8fd4eTHZ4Mu/GSHw3rzmjyj3rzkjOoNewml@p5kiTVD7u9SVPjmdHF2RohDL0@gpjqa@@lEu51yhPyDU3f1IUxtF0q87Aa6vD6kRcQXymt8rjbFxdsCH39b/7kprl6REcKfv69kPf/g/l6TMeJLVPHLa9mjR2cENbpb9pO9TNyKRITMC0I@8wbQoCmlVIKDCwkGlDsMkDEd/XVMbMCGkH6JXTj0DLtJizoThFJLbvhMagLO4ALw8QTy007kO5JNdWFq1LOTj/hJHII2gOQf7CRP8K20EKi/zF5wm6ikn6@oBsHrYzRpNcyWJKBjc7muJ2UtJx9nbvb1TB2bZv7m5O3lslkoZTtkGV3caJgJKy75hhElk6sIcjW8xS98AOpn/IjyyobROWTY5l1AB/c7XdAu9b4MFJXngjph1kvgPxq7QT/Cjh40qKsiFdwf/QD5GG@fX7M2gu5fmKvBBda5iFuwHKCXeR64G1Jx0NnZzFG9HzkfPA9iCk8jr1gni2rehmvMK8wl4KFM3OJ@Dp/9a3Zy5Rtm2YnnkvmlmkYtOsz7@jg/PMzGh3hbEHq1JCloXK/fWraluhOB8xpc80w7iE@Q/9cO6w2eW4T@AlbZ@cwQu@xHGy0Ch3YwLmCnAzGwzOEqgNYQjIRIAiqn0gpowuduULSSbX1CbYhTQk/KnNsg2xCTozSh3qiLHeM5dDBi56eBoTeHgPAoydSZKVW1bt6w6ctgjup5C2ZzjTFlCNkzb0A9Zk044U4MbmRUucuoyf0YJfNK8Ul@@WRsihkQc2nb6aTE16kOPTAa7nVXK2BHL4Fx@w4It/pIAF281wwm1u6OFtCQ/TMDw3l2dEFqMcbCkjVQ@O/E6xEHsm7VhnKBODlSc7kpfyJETOiqQ/8I8rKWwvm4KAJCkHXUcQ@hEgRzA/x20QitTZaNeoOOvpkdSSpRf/JkMsAgtxipE92bcWd4L2qQX8Wc75S5YIMCyJFnJ1oq5GbrB1v3kbB0RF8yJE0a2QelRT3nVcVHdm@KUo96dkVWRt1ng@yeAWrESh6JDeI4z6jX2aMpCNLghC0aDK2/1wBvXRIZlR2ZkXCuL/wh/qEFur@k@LfxuEZJficBDiCMDR0wPuNedYEVISCVEBv04Lv6gFjtDswnR/FQDXARrI0k2Sz4RE11MiDkVgVWuraYIqB2EFVMRk0tQpT1ks2yvpzvLZZ4dVTOORDuolT1IIgHa9hhdGDVonlaUhLFdRmpq5CcBw8ynRtC1i2MkXT0I0bJPCJmHK9EObdFl5QQfwnGq0mhbeJQX5WMP8gD@oTfnQ/SQITVq8chPkIz8ny/XDnOp7mDptfxhwm6WLdKCYAncgGdFXn0s@nclaFtft4gpAjofT1SeqeVuK2oukLpaVkUW/xkIrY4tD1X9YijDWx9pB6/VPRBCRlvf7I8LLO0J/YXYQr6TwSU7@0qGlcujLR93Ujm6MAnedTNw7qB@XruXz@yHyc2qTg7I3N8yafxrxrqgg/i4/a5gM/SqIZLcTeDaU66DK@qkFxMnkrbM9PW3i/L4JgF7q/VHwOnzrVg0x51h/Qi1GzhV1fruVQA4yRADg4grxR@7UTcInaIpOGU/9RCKnvnUo/8XHeyUJDlJzqs0qDzARGCsV5uiuZWEMu/kpPT7dmKq8HyXQMtOawfdvjSzLtCstvgsvzWuKyXI6ade3iW9yrCFo/v2cfnxWk@QEv9dN3Mu7xREcCHy0EspgVaXg3DYL5qrfCV2/1h3zf48qUahvyLhy@5Y/88BjG5BzHzJIjxD2irOQfe0M49D/VA23YFDzlX2CPjrePxaN/YeOvkeHXJFYYz/5w2XmNY/joxbPNurS2coOqAiD8mB2JdK3t61tW9Pcv6uxta1tub4cffzPD/2Qz/Aw)

### Explanation

While poking around the other day, I noticed CoffeeScript 1.5 added a command line option for literate programming.  Literate programming has been a pretty successfully method of adding languages to the polyglot, so I explored it a bit. Literate Coffeescript’s Code indicator is a line starting with some whitespace (tab or space), and the code block must be bounded by some empty lines, much like Literate Haskell. A quick look at the polyglot showed that this syntactic requirement had thus far not been enacted. So the only real difficulty with adding another CoffeeScript answer, was finding a place to put it.

@Potato44 and I went back and forth for a little while about where the best place to put the code, but I ended up putting Literate CoffeeScript  `console.log 178;` immediately after Literate Haskell for a couple reasons. First, our polyglot has done a good job of using logical groupings for languages, so putting the literate languages together seemed nice. Also, I didn’t want to group the two CoffeeScripts because I had to add extra lines, and doing so prior to the Klein line would require me to re-work a couple Klein answers – not to mention hiding the line from all the other scripting languages. Second, placing right after Haskell allowed me to use the blank line at the end of Haskell as the blank line at the beginning of the Coffeescript code block. This was important because the code line and bounding blank lines would be 3 lines to insert, which would throw an error for Retina and require a 4th line to keep things happy.

### Others

<s>I had to throw a `p` at the end of Haskell’s code (commented out)</s> (This broke Curry so the `p` was placed above the Mornington Crescent) for alphuck since the new CoffeeScript answer required a `s`. Incident also had to be re-worked, as usual. But this time I ran out of space to put new tokens in the usual places at the top of the polyglot, so I started a new line of incident tokens at the end of this line `#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyYyY` This space has far lower linguistic density than the space we’d been filling for the last several answers. So hopefully we can keep filling on this line for long while.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure towards the top `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is still available for incident tokens if I'm not mistaken.  Adding there shouldn't cost bytes.

Comment: This is broken in Curry. There is an easy fix by moving the `p` from the end of the Haskell to the line above the Mornington Crescent.

Comment: Curry should be fixed, The permission to do so is linked in the edit description

Answer (score 9):

## 184. [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 9870  bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_      7 )(22)S    / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  # {((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or'wWW s'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1  
#  
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180
#  \\
""""  
#  
#  \
=begin  
#p :1*23!/5x%6E0 !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
;set print'-';print 89;exit#ss
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\| R"12"R _* ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/| @  %"18" ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +    <>
x    x xx     xx                +++   +   e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"60"e.0,1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=los*81''cagem x=4721en nd ogola=1ay $0C0 00 3cod/|puts_e
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]   )[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//      $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/pppppppx     eeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001584

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9SZFVLJV0S/dWldSSqurepliqZDJJZonM5M0kJbJUuuhZG73zWNi7Pb2D3h7v3O7ZNTyAF/BgbQO7mAEMeL8uBvsb7nwyBob7H7TPORH54kNS3Z7xmhKZkREnTpw4EXHixIlX0/C7v/1tCj/syO1NOj13yIaWP2Qtz760PI09mbDHhu2vF1clCaFqXmfUt5yhX5JSTGfMdky7Be9s6F5Yjv3B8sC/yNjAczue0WfDrjFklm8aA8tn7mg4GA2Z254fbZWxvb773s5hzL7tdABsaHkDzxpS@Bpjr5ye0W@2jKmQ9akEBx6E@@yp1fvY/zhkptvvG07LB8gNxl64nm8hvGn5vovRNxkb71nmFNItADU8231ee/n5VNA2Y58DicagZ42Z0fSHnmEObddBnhTYyctXJ0dTMXSdvT7d35/2LbIvc67D9kfmxXTQKnvl@UbPmMa/xmqjoXswnPZfZ7WO5RisqG1rxenADfbEM2aibDLPMlptu2dpUCAsx7pWb2B5DH1Y2/XYAZDU2ypsFc5rUUzNxLhbUSCLBfJacuS5rZGJJTjsWpAxLHVE6ksmUFFlA1HXNHSwFJHBwQD1idu34szwmWNZLeYPLNNu2yanzhoPLceHBH2N2cC8K7vXYy2rBxEi7GaW@S4b@TGvZs/oaqYmYe4wFda/6DGbmYMB40GsZwNJ@4UtZmFdZB8gvNf12XjQZ77dh@Ch6bbblsU@WIMuk1quxOBjDqYyFb4tWwDjWAFjrAHUKWSMi1UQuBTw58ozBsB8X3BgaPehxdjDtM8sw7exTUIU33JaxNNB2FpdZjhxdrFLG@oMZHzkEW7f8qjUCC@UsGcBSiNsL8qVZw@Bl8iLGjuyDI@depalJltuIklIzMUUhpgRjYp0Zye9d7ifhqLlMTRjAEXprZ7@6AvJYFqFLZ@X4VuR5bK09/Ipu14@QzdvqFD8A08xVFb5lvn5szMLvmO9me94NxJglYArPZZ3B8O8kRsAgbkhEJg30Imu3GVRG/RiCbOdqbKIVTgO1YLSgPrLXmcpZ@bI81AYRUw1LiDTPdfpAD8hs97IQX44bKMARWC6IEuyzLoErkHjpTJyr4jDp10bCs3HIom1NS5SiaEgVKESC44G6fpub0RwENMfYk0GrkBUxHjQZq9Z27B7GAXCERWn2rP8UW@IcUZOC0seRKbV0lhAhum2EKjvXkJyBiAlD6j4/VirJKIAGArCpaxi0Pf/7E9bnQ7gqZmm67VEdX3NWq5Jwt8gYkGiMqywrmP0iCyAy2LqPDokcGn07JYxxOSdiUiCiKBUr9xRr8VcSNC7sqGNdo1LaNfQtMyhxSs57y@yrG9ccFli85oLGe8bTShYSoDSpmzn2ONdKCXTklJUZ3L90bC9xXKDPZb282@VRyXl0dKZBcSpmrqynM93ylDhtBXygrf0bTXndS0hPP2h4bt2SxpMhl3XKbKcyWSz4g4sR0kncKSzaa@ZVjWUcYpatium1radlpLegbpYhYTTatmsmHW71ChPRY8nCWiuEA02V0sxVVkCkUON4jLfN2xHG0zY65xwxcJc/xxZjsFazBsZM@13yT1S1F9ivXSxgoAc0vyeZQ2UgqarKCYQbm6@MWBeTqdwiAyX7EYmnUpn4lknDJDTREaxsZ7aLoqt3qCLXSUwxfEH0A94WHdNA2qPj93BEJSWLGtSvaY@BCQLycQrK@1ZrAmCNKhH1CR5k8P4ORSUAkPUhJIt2WrFGjIIAWjLQ39GGvfcK0iQaMJOBkSHg4kaHSgaiMwzUuMZ4SmRTzJLFw4IFMTWtNhWrmlDI8DmBjJd1PlY3gB8tchhABtvJDHZ0zcmgMXknWrUYJjdhrbUB/HgTZhpocwB4WPxDgUTGVH780FNQ4WtkCuuryfb2EwTG3r5Wu7HIKQ/5G9tSZj5pMoAPU/bumI9w@mMjA5qig5EMUzTGgyFoIKc@EMQRdP9DXnmROep@V1p@fF02tSJBIpFlAYKeV56ois0ULoIXTHXA2HKDKHtspbtgVjqTaZTB4DLqcTldwiSIOCdvICEQAOASmaNLXM0BKkGFfiqa5tdqLNIncPlIu@EppMHr3jqINlz7TBpJEavPixKWj70QjIWoshhic7igc4VUVUTHlT4cY/bMRt@fw5iNyQROoKYr5Y3NKh7d@Dsu447BykwMkSLIMkQXg6giZ2gOgkdV6B2UWMNdcywiKDMQGpAy4f61x0OB34J@gl72B01Nagp@VNvcjA8dLCy5IfexB663N3suU0Qyz60z3yQQt4cNe3xVIbILyzD9750CQpY22cV6Lm/GUGtU9JtHwQm@e8icCxIJsFNKPivDIAEpAGjlLZPongfhMrJxDEVWaOmpEGjk7NMxoYrq@DAWCFfdt0@SiH2hhQD1PRg5GA7bZBWQuaTyDfmdnWh7Ce9Lp3W3ru2o1ynl5aW0qV0FST70tIjcO2g6xG6MuB6RK4cuRBOQxfFyJILQ@sUA/0a6Zt6gHmsNrDYxtgrfbAHilEvlVYbWaOui2cRnyqIOpBsAJ3DB@BJq5UKOlVVrl5BRrVmO5n7XZTOJ6ZnDwQTvjAuDf4uuLBKbLD7A9dDBbaMneztPOlXPOgFQWk1u4qXPqsXzhpn12etzNlNOoux1bJRaUKmID2lr3U8dwTdpVpfK@X0hqrWV6GTbFbShfSKomzlepCQoaqfbakZg3NbSVsgtZWzszQwVfCnbnY9wjfOFlU1ZBXQgR0z6IRKWrvegvSbakPNpCGums7CEKOSTgNnTGSCT5nGmplg0OHxl5wxu5mMRNXQ9S7wOyP2wU@D4RWPvg/1d/fkeWKs278A6cpMv4eqSM7j2gi85le4Z4seocZVYgeksTrQ3UIOoLdthSMjx3Vyzoj0Z1Ju3XhCNBhECPLDvgflqp2AQcRtewwDBGj3k0ARwv4bdaFdGG66MFh@Q6qJzKDhMGzu2lxt6Ih3K5rpR3UA9B5wDnqGCQ07ie5MZmeAEOp5Pj8/RC3PIJ5WlWhUc1ceoWMxDQf517JJax/ZfhfZC5oVDiW8NnAVVXbQDSzi2gEzoc/vAKetsT3kOjzUoxOM8szwFRW1xhrXulDZQ40BiQosANSduyaMdyzQHDCUDx7ZnnNpe66DTNb2ADVU@DKWwRTyeeyFalSrHRSfLubvPOTAsRlvPcbbONZp5pq@yfKO23M7LlsBAKyamsYr9oFjAgmg8w1heMl8@wMxqNZxYeCTrIMWdvc@6oj6xmqofRsImSd47T3IGjY/0xHAgjyfHPx4D3oIfb1QAPqDtwJ9wkzGsEznET1NFgEIq18P6w2W5I@tQXfiJaqT74pRJNQn1@INk4/rDehQgSrRwj9Q1Hgj5z7QzoOgVuCal/c90pDQlBEfZSRyD8ogtFORHd5sIIepKW/0DViRQDpT4FH57oPsPO2OLMkyuy6Tz0DDKFZZvmVd5lHgyCDouqAq5yApyyNlLIwmrJDS0B2BVteyenbfHh6QsavnoOoSdctB6C40sAjBkW0NJTHeiMQrGqQiWet0OPzeGDskX7LoyV4ePt07P6qdPqvI@ZHv5Xt2E2pwyzrvg@LZs3yZTX9S7NgCZCL@h4vesesOK7y4Lnrszk8K4wTRnz89f37w5Lh2/DUngtD4dn/UM5CU0vIUAEY/oeCgVcWsgG3P7YcauS8KYnkVWW8lzMY4PBWhaxg6EkbjmP8G@vfREKyZUsc0Wc7lr6GnANxEQDQOUx/WyWQQkozFoaeA3CKUaDDWvGbguY2eoak4YUSN0M0LXxxJYL7WCzeI3HdG/iCWs2tdJ//LYbuNvXboXSTvixxW9V7kvUre3NScNPIKtswEzQUO8a0RPm6inotvJmgucIhvneND0/Z8dFMh80BDZBuEDE3hc3FNBcwBDDFtEqa4@TwK26KwRbZzkdbc4IWReHM4BQH83IVu87nt0zRKvH1IoXp3JsmBjppQxuQopBjZiljucr6RS44jopYLjevCxaFR5DovaPo6YglR9C96szHboGHQTwJ0hqjZEC4x@s02/cwBKAn7CQhHnA5ArnyBNmA08big71lXBEYjQUIG3LIdI39MDxwTzqMnObpNENO02iNQhfKgqqP7DrDc9hZBtptNexEo8AVJD55zwLxRcx7bYGTanTGAsATjhyNv2LNa4vmfftKCApgtnq4xIfUvdJwD36hutBeWloiKL/Qzv2QJ5v2oZxvEBnLdhdI00OZs9ELHfNTYj7Fcrmt4fdSyROFC5cQfEH231DNOuWf1Ri0reM5PhFicNLPw2I7dpxzBE4cJNChaEH3KSMTjk6Ldc40WYeHqsG1Fpc3LxRpzxTCmb0Hvcg86A1sOiyZPht3RcMR/cb7krnK1B/idz5VSspIV1o2mbuVd32ja1i31wDMuRi03N7joUKaRtI1FtZ03IjQ95No944I7z9E5nwE8i57d6Vhe8FwEdtUFDY9U0/wVPW6pKkH/ykhjMm7D6fX47yKQYNI7dCzmk92jn0@pkFRFTGg1yFqcEs3F2GRPMbZnNCeoonc/vWZhgqS4gOCpmJlMYRW7s9ACHk2@DgaL42MfSPG3t@fH5pOxnCXzFNc8n4TNcfME5VlMy97R6qHnsvtGL1dsxZwLhXhg@opcc0BpvJYze4YPlWkoisO6hOKjn9sqOHZGJlaryHVL9Y7ICSZCFtnUozgD23R7tj/gLU68LJKm09bICA3OitNPFBXfZvnbIpXI7@ZC13yB4JpDtGsvqG/3EHDcpIxG@1gF0txFvDPdK/wuVDG67qXFf@d3eh/mUnUPUZXrUc2wzTnRW@Zd1RVnRulnPhcv5lI1NHtz/Uvshet6XcvxWVErBEY0nJYyej1u4z49OFxcp3275/owQMPf23gBAzHf57/za3Ocbbbh5MjSGHfPjyaIGjBNWFYWFKbR67i9ja1O3oCfhSU@8trYA4jnfSVfKLl0/W7JFShIrqOL50KRf5H3Lu6qDGSO9HDaIua8pb@dJ76EuXtxBmEYgXOR8zO3X9iimFqej5YXFYBndq@MSfD8Ab3KIu4GvcpgQuo16H8YYXsLHEOPq9w/JLW121Nr3U8mzaDdvCsTscK96Fkgoel3pkhZsaB/Ygy9ULi/hGr3RtbImisxDpvvLVycdousuD9RBZGNZWFXygPz0KoUQn0Qg8d7UY39N77dKmCMng2N/E4tZ668G4BOPsDx9hE4jtAxG7HjjAaJwo3x7njkHN/Oue4gaNluK0EkhnyqRNq6W5dKqO2@Rd9FKv5e34UhstsHncG5R/kLpGSK478JxOQTYX5vo43TuxVviYXzm6DXgv4BpWpf@Dk0lN5P8BQXje0JeHsbRm@ONZzg7yJuzxOkTdftfUrpgDxt2aiWgbKJKw3vKqUZXUdMdbPIiuGjRaTZXmS/4H2NGGgC93BQvbCgjyBLQ@oc7lPKM7bWW3qtmOX1rvEm9NhkJPI9M3AvovcYG7eubWmbtxLM1VG3afUM/hhvrN2Gb1tbvY9KNAj0XLLUo3Wf2/OjCZHUlAgaTIBZdgvGKl2rb9HrLUq@0Xo/8oPHQqCxi985wVqerNML4g1saPMO/ibmDmJa0dB1YHQ1NLyOhcOTHk5qCd9FcjYwes9l7kHf6Fj7d1auyEqB66D4oC5yzrdXlPjSBBOi3SFJ@MjPdS6siR885@vHExPKc9S/Fdu8dm6iMfTOhq3l59r671D7nK7bdbpW16PGEb4tah5QI4d8ZfptmQD6u4Z/gQu/SCZFw7quH@duz@317sNdlIlcQrrufDvtHi7ZbkHUT8I7MZoQIB53mvSg6yYmUR@@qO10rRH0UL47dAdWjt4WgfbQ@MN/55ueDw7TPntjW16Lz1qjJdAY2s2exa5sIOG9H58qnW9YavZcA9cW3qLEA2eC531MVabr3WkH6RjucDCgx/mgN/Lph0y@ufZ8W2aJ7ROl96kM9pAvGOBV1uq4TbNr30VS0zKGjn2RD2w6/HV@NU8KY8q5zXJP0Vvr2cArb6JhJajEw0/wcTC/4dvPxcaSWxWS3ZHnTe4WDsmp4ND8yicN0LHIACNm7eYEU9ePq2KC1R@3zFyISb6FNYqUaVScc1YBtBN9oTkosQBIsKC3ujq8g0uma17cqU8sNGSK@WEy6dmxOW7wn7Zi3E7GMyHfYHSoPBt1fPXuitttgV6FP3MrSa3DKwhOLPk99ypmeIambzjiMTdu8fndqdPsyPqtEyUlpj8/rx0e3I3M7NkDn/@yXLs4V1WYndudhZrMH/uKompZbf57l37Xdz1cBw2KRM70LN9EOzjKYC4bueBx3A7I4lyPRcAB7FzyZ6eS52koyX4u99VLq2PguqjnNi6R6vmzXR9gnp5Vvg/iH40M3/7RyB1ac3FOzy7fB@ULo2ObzxIlECAMuCsW0fBHQlii12xBXHVtn5ajBo5FegRUtNvF4bTBPdwadbtxJKYjibWBLHfAgjWEoQNN/hhuzE0rrr67g8m9uiSypYrn3Po0f07@NuvC1ag/GPniMVcF5jP3x7SBKFxq7mfFCinwsz2xz8XXgs1kKVpNRgvPg4XILIXL4UcoGYeupzGCUxQjk1FViUdCI3PHAbAAirbz4FJ/vlPIZz3bHxKs3Wb1Olu@HpcKJf2GVZhcklmjwbHihxae740HtBfnmEevLxuNynI6l0svp8@cEiukQ3CrBxydC24kYNs2PTi9EQuYY/A1g@gOclzmWxn8Lm0TAm2iBVrJKxjMUs/kenxBPt/tcYqz2//xL1pi9xQMXXzWt0G2AUNw66Dbt7ru1SOerki9NhgYuPsKcUBT6PG9ALndGvOvUH3hm6bcK/Zq/3RLbMUQ@xTh5Qj72RgVvHBxHI0LKYe88Dg14aI4kXAYK8iU6fZGfQcUxtaw62vsxKY1kiMvWuwELgRzhh5qza0sO2AtC@cQaekrDRR7rntBa9iRkv/4F3wDCi2AFQsTg@Rp41ksRVznqtOuD9N0R0B1gOSD5bkCREEmQ3MYoRkGmpbF/VVcFko7Y6BG5oJ9IZQM3xyyWzthuT2Wxi2YuNy8bLeV5drx56/rhUblW9bPW//pJ3n1WjBO/iy3veHLWRaAlG@wYsWD1yE4Ck0zeXks8wTD1cG20E6ueHkAiwxeyXCBcFDHXHcgWg3t7aOtbGFtFNuUFXRTOQcbRPq0LZAqrHVFG0RoVZ6DYgL32zk@NDB4VQk1b3WVZWXELQW5kyFbhwRxk40BLr6RkNbL4mYHjLI8Zh9ZFytZzsQ1nPDGGdnD/TX9ypNgUclqfOlP/qnVHNF892VRK65WKDvL55WdKrk8q@XiPrf627NxsZA7G2/uNfJ@wNSzs/FnheJXwHUXBjHLD/PY8vZePr1e1qqFjx99Y8Jk@SZd5qubQEwsXx8dHO2dnNZOX51AKdwE4mff9fpGJGuwFtGqzK7box2EwBfPtvxPkD/hG4ArCls22A5ur1ZVKb7gkEAFr@WcvMydMdGUiH1H9HnxfSsWPgsgZFrbZkGNihaqQ2@EhQm1DtmHXBgNcEMkE0jEpi6qbjYKe2xJIYdwMdkcoUo8k1kFuJYDrt2TZ2xxrh9xv/uw7k4st/Pv0VwQZF2YXj0M51mcy4Kbv5d8D6DH/N3zzbHcnm@CuSXfABr6BnH2awfPXx3vJaNBZaMnid/K9rpYcsulNDY5bm0IdrHR7gQREc0tFZnJFIG/il5thPubmtbwyoJsCSlp9nlkqqFEvyxFFRM4U8GTCBplzgtFIQpQGSljtqZWBLftcYzEoLOOobvmWQylwb4cog4I12SBOUUb@jX8BNlArIJdQRs8ImkuBHfaj@tB2aDFYdawswbNjWIt6LPC7sdn8B/rngJXscHGTPRreoPlWBG@PQvGL90QVi3zzootc0bIy5x2OaQXt5MDTa33Bo13aF2SWPQM3XXPGODeVQH9EsYYJfbNyKUdFoEwCRWNK9SjDX5uAhWtaWBuaOeGM8R9qEEHRvgO9k8qqKZxHY0EfbzOjRzssQAodo7B3hjUY6hsbRL6fEc0Z7krNt8GfSaZwXyx2S5UF3x2aftkJsNCaKOy0wNJibkRGcdzKGhvDav1fFBOWtCPg6oyxD4XtBSNltvyNbc5h8kpqJNaqDtmmSwhrF@Z3YwJfeqVCf3rOx55meAIsy/N2TV@ZuW//2d/yneKnw3B/QfCPS48gbc/Em9tcP/TIETX4e2fh29FePsZf3ubR47Obo/luQmZiAx8fXDEfLLkIYv6xjiWe2y4WJS2M4Ji7QOvL4l1CM6zFXEmwqPUXwPnobiA7ag@oMZA6VleQ8HNjaV8HrVrnH7RaBmoNeZmPNrr@M0I9/iDkpPfWN9Y0/NAZO4yQEgbjjq47pAjVNUSiBrp0h5U3jVNtrOzw2TfNHpWZaPMWZ5fNt6uyu9CQpcBVuKKeJ1BHIgSxYCwqoimLBsZXcWo2D@k9TSKipbLSxC0LYUcAKKitxPs2AB1zhWsgurhWOMhaSSTYIABctChPQAWP@khQJQDRBw37kSfruXRSkJceB2r91q8GOQ3CHaCYCV5XiWrv2VnwzOnIU4kYFBhfjWnyjng/sM5xxSEtac2uz9emd7djrlhj08cF1ec7gO1TCnmi6t5fUONtSlZoAJ6sQV9BJTQZqANmpb93h34td29gy8Oj05m9nkTZHoaLM3S1Z3MWU7L1huhIz1V6wOmPtnPn7x4sh@wMk5VNBGLENFs7DSZ81KbpnRB6m/4Es7ZtClgJiG9cF/ENO2R26cFC7PYo9B8DHCXLx2bSVVRr2/qjZ3qmZOaSf7jvLMvUtoKVi5wnfl08kWazZE5B8HC1FM8lsnXgj0NRTk62SXcwcDfI@/FO7XDQ56i7drBEliJNlKF@6gkbcHiWMi7ludJ0V5lTlhAL8iagFQdSY0SNKWZyfQ4NUzkZfY8KrHZI2TSIbfR0BEUhgPDcs82ObRPAppbcujcBBjDH8R6Y7NLC2ho5DmhkTyIitCE3bLJymR4wQ6eMOTE6tu504AeFBzR9mux77gLeevZzbJRqY9ZuP/jtl3Imj/o2UMFt0SPNbSQQG4UFTOg7@Ce4rG6s90Q27dZsMs6Qxu1j0bAryN3wCLr1FMrcB2DisKejgC5ieObL0Z9gGvT49jCXsICpSUHkYGP6YCIOm5NFnnQ@q11SF3rWuOW3YGeRlGzIJI@0/Voi7eBe5SdNMhhzqrPcYVhnDGftC09xjGjbmi207LGCu4ALDWQO@CfvnpzmVblmTpAe@PFTujW9Cb5QFgYQ9Fqow3mUwJhezsUBMm2s72tdX0J9@eAMgwpngy95@CEPlRp940BU0Z0yoDPNEavypniZP2hp7JcFfuzK@awTIYG1fCgANCVEbRNLpu2cyp4KI@Sr0A5o6/vtPDxwR6wuq5pDXBTIipbRoPaLqgbaIpSJRgbQZQSoYUOGP5KSBEonS2kiD@XKVmJNvoC1NxgasidLjVA4AXlmlUfRrsqYy2Qc3V7uyRKIykOtxlUi505EgPQzhFzgW4K/BU7LIBrKMQAatezWjYIlMdfWo4D7VWBOtOH1smMEVQyT80G5@Flo8OGKIUUJ/GZ2LIBhCYPIdpLX/dc0GeW82WyzZRvoN9/d4Ydf1t0/ZP8f53X8uVrZblXmeRBGVOrynK3omdWVzKZZWdFWXZQHXn4EE06N8ug7ZxrMDAaA1BuuaeWoT6DdlRZdsrLxo6y3KoUVygGvMLQ7BoifOvntetl4ya//BC0iSz4eLx1Kss@nQ9Q0DT9BujDFrKcz0KducaN7nTKHSa/bGcySIO2fI4EfJs/O8lQv3J2kifrUVkouflOPxAjSV0lLImZ0/k4A4V3KZTo6yjRxXKb8wA4OoJodV7Yrdr1l7g4kdE8quX78fqVDLm/YBECDYWTEDIKP6ABGDhWgIn4mjVUFYTJb3@b0jcYkx9trCpu5tF6oZxJr@swPIRxXeoxKKr5FdmTr8@e5i6ZlUvX28a69k3j6OLo6Cv1TGHbLJ3aPZT1Nfkt2y6y@302WXHBh/0un1RqJS@l8iv6w818/t27d6CSw6de1aogPvhHrefSjbqyyVh1c3Mlu7G1kn2cPg@oUpViUT2hIRE7s2174Lda8HW7dCSlkuKfR48oLRh2wj/jfiJ94QheEET4pj4VzlhPsbNNw1jJrBUfO2Wgbhs/q0wHJ/5uwVdn6@tsDz9/87/9zS/@5uf09wv6/pXBLtgH@Fy0Gf6T@0Mr5jbQ3Wx/wPMTQPeukFwYpNPrq@mTt2n2/9lnienVR5v/@eeH36SGqWox/8aD5zD1TWpjK8Wd4IC31eDtMlVN7SDYxk1qkq9UKuDc/M//C8SvfgF4MGSyAz/V9QDXxiRVzVUoysdUdQMcerEI6f5fP/mJlKqOUx9Suq6nJvR3niro@Nl6qD9kDBx5eXNLdt3HAb3j2Cfwy@t68Swqz1hxY9GG3l1IB8qVuakkKLnDWsVEbSDHp8DhoaUbS4/fPWXMgq4WP6XS4xmGP596P9Zy8NFEMxjjS24cZCG1Vcme8@TDupqKOaYyHP4ykffw/RPhpFRw7FuubrQbCa6fpfSttcPH43t/WER0wMRUxLswcTbtF3A9fGFBo2efAielvq1Ujof496KJf0cn@PdDxRx7BJ8l@KN/@ISv@LtEPsKbQGY/S79Dc5VS9VS90fhRl/48/Hvm4F/zG/x7/gH/fjTEv1MT/45/hH@LMiOldnZ2UpnMMaiGos7e5/MKvpp2Lt6Cuovo/l4/bO1w4/CxxFK5RiZ3c1PX3o4z5bL4B6WpHL7hh7uArMZNLrfztprJ1Im8elXQuZNrVIFWTjL9vN0BxJmd@s6Odl6tVnONt9X6TjKSiPf4cQbb6WOIWG3U61LqGsuigj8r@GP6@FuU5Ty9YmcBvfM2uBg56SE8GB0ajO9S6t3OOyXzKPOo0CtcFvQL/eKFexj9Hx6OIcAeF967XqFb6OotkIisYL0qTAqTcaHvHuotcFrwV@iD0y60x4VOwSk4uj4ZJ1At/u8fusMXhy5gcyHmcFwYIuJCG56dw8MXgK8Nab@HP7tQKIyByHHhEv4LPRTUdJgMPd@eq2dnUp3J7yzo/jU9rRXS2kY6bTfWNwbfnF3fFDe@qdOQaX27Ucezgxoyy6bPz@rpRjmV98/O8lxdkotrcpkOF7q5OT9/WjutnZ/nsWqNd5YzjzO5x/CpVDM74vEo1aqWH52VcliovFJq56n8zqOz6moO3RsZKLki@O3kM5/4iVDCs7p0JqXZ1Zs3b/D75uryirvIwf3O3oSh@PMmD17chV7wQdD8vPgJBwP98x/ov3X4/6//F6@YUm@ojCnXNzsKfVT8U9Xrm@sb8VtVFUW8KDvwhx7wjlGub6roJKBrcNUVtaHe3HA/@FXUHY6wimnsVClyBHiNEv2ap3uWLoPmV1lWxCTP2dm4UFDLTfAJ7dLGR5ovUMu0pGK5iXM8MErQV1QCWV8rl9eEe3OrXN4Sbn1jo1xeCaEK8CKcAGT5hlnG6l5OqUgCHzMojI5wk/WzcbHNijLaZZRtFYZl@ioO/jfWmVqtbqyDx8aWmlMKaLfhUc7kwWBwJmtkqdZoH1OlUvM8Y4LWKWUNkCjb65XKmWx452dyvdjAuOu57Q3merntVVVW1bf6zg6kgUkUVfCW02PZ9dJQO5mfTt2kiElsbV1VmhNLXdtQtjLb4q@yBMWlyKvpVRzjpI10vf54ZXVlc63@qLHCVvDLVpSds2pjkcagplMgSoK2X9FJZDIUAeVro6LfVK6NEtoEbsqmOByt53aY8fDh6vbHj/pWAaEBgQyfICp4SJWm1QGi4W3ASvpKcXUpvz7@bGOvwJY@ruCnXq9vFbcyKyBlVra3G40G@X5ckso468VHsLk0l1Jsa5sKLQWjxnp/3G7QGSqVXF3fWG/kUPN4P26vQEr65mpqRRrQKpTNAmvh/J3H3HZ7CTy7hs@aONXqW71ecLTclev1Wld2y1qSUkfPa7t7p9niDqAs7td2s8WTV09SOr6uR@8UvIrvx3u1p4evIMLR873ayd7nB6/3Xh2Bvw/9m@Rb8OkfGdbIOreuRqMrfD@36LNr@8b798ZgcA6VZzBuf/@rn37/q//2@1//7Ptf//T7X//iN9/94qfw/Qv4/ow/f/Zvt9fx9zff/fP/8fs/@zV4/hV8/wN8//1vvvuXP@Ffev9r@P4fMb@/Ft8YHP9C0QC2P/rNdz//8998909/Cd9/Jb6/nP5@/yf/jv//n@IPnb/@/k/@Gn/Ey09/Bgj/7i9/hf8//8u/@w@/wv//6V//3V/@i7/7o39Djj/ljv/7X/1b/vu3v/fTv/3Hf/y3v/fdgt@f3vr73T38v/sH8Lk/nffBc598farPdz@Int@FG1EqVKl@8Yff/8vfh9r6J/ztn8Ab/IdBfxC@JEL4yx9EL4Dhf5gT6Q9/890f/3n49vtJwEQYIPkDCPuzRNgffP@rn3z/5//N97/60@9/9UconnJr29laNqffMRQBwPV7wCHgxn3gAFAXRoElqUhP/BGebIlc4xVpfRUHCzn@yXDPj8uoBrKzj9I6vGc@5lEzZPmPIvQMt/vqELq6RqEFUGMLGLqOr0EoO5b1onzMzlcYmnkeBaNnPsDghKx8fMwAGCIzCP5M1rdkAfiIE/qRx8l8jOcsgzEpfCkkHL4i9BFlVcRPDM923r2rVBHgMQTvwDt54i@@gM8TGANU8AOP6harSFm2VcFzxRCwAu8Ujk56B1x4l0hFesqe4JALvZ8Ch7hlg42ld@wdh2QIu0VxJAj/FjyecH/Chqi@lcArw32ewvNbAT@WCB/@CxsJuvEbBMBPhnE/eM0gkkzAJv6zU5U4HBN2lsjcEvIUB40EbS0fkYq88nQFfnX431vyJUwiM8Z/FiUjEshIwKZMNijaRNqZyEsKXzMzqQcxpKmwTBTGKM1MElWGzSC8LTDhLU1HZHOxCAoWhk5lMwidk2IQmpqNEgbFGZTJJBmGMZOZykgZXPW8IhJdyaygMZytfOpH0EQJzGXHLZ84v1einMfxRtRHWIleHiFDsFHaEMTVdppPA317jamSQgfUqjQ@twYDeL7wO0/cMVMKWVnO6hvb3Cwthu9fu6VS5Vt9bVOCJ72P8GxccUorVGC8L0XbgQ9QIFWvc@jcQSfoeBtStSrmBJkuVU/2TiHC6SHTiwWN1QuN67XN4tr62npxdWNjfbOor21sr22sb60W9MJGYb1Y1LfX1ra3tjdvgKDHIKqzpZXm@k71H818/qt/NO8z3xc/UvUrNtbY0dGPcjdSdZzL5YtEckVf3yxPKkAIeUlVUl@5aju5zvk@w@W50hnpzNe4FAhIk65z2JofwIdJDyT2ALzgA5hxRoSJmeiDw7KYr8STx/mcpayvb8vA6jPLaXFs0iD@kbDgHq5ts4c6d65vRM4COqVTPKP/JSQA5eCw57ggceiyU5cvfHtimQsgdrv8lp1dzwVd/YfDPDGcCx701MYz2sxhGPTMwBNY/L497C6AeDXo434Uy/sHw7DXbwKBaLTlAE/gx@u57jyATfbqaEEuX4TbrXD6k/ZbAfjxwefPTmPP073a7jNpgz05fPl06rEugNbZ87390/B1k4cGUddDFF/vPX8@/SoeOOpaYuub2aymafCDzyx96Kktvw1AdG2xUiNvFGRLK2T17PnEgvHXdS5307Gblr4B2saanIIBH57RfMJPoR7CUHjcpsbQc/2VLT2dNo2O1WfjCjRhHWo5LortuD0YiMKAermwWwDtha1Cnc5/RPPWuSW9wJVj2zrfYWD70jMY@vXxwF/cFzyUPKsFZFw5tHmiiZdrjAZsoSc80Audnt3pgni7ckMAH2pr0zAYfD/1Azis@Gd4u8eQp0F@MyG9WXDpKrSKvQlMYKEpjDf5N7imlzb2BJPw/tDw8Dq5UxS1dOMKwy2nTTyknHZyoQZDmy7pSHELBO@2JOHEo91mBUlD4VUsbm@tb22vFreyW9tba@swHl/P6sWsvrm1uQ21oKBv6Rtb69t6dmtte3UNxC6Erm9vSikQTXY7n4duRZdletqOicdB7uC5mq7WrUqpltXGhsLGSktlqVboMdpi8urWWYFBRFnCta0r44pcXMOF56s602VJNpjJUvv7u4X9fVl@gi9oO90tyHILX9a3CoXNJ7JsUcgudA1FiNTFt70NNLLKso0vu7X9fcTwHl@KW4hDli94CH/pBS@bAObgy@oqImCy/E2IrgDIXU7RFsUa8pdC4cmuLI84ebj/DeBq/G2NiN3DFwzASPs8ZBfCZPnzIBK0BxnUeIITST0L8luryfIBf6nVEMUXlPl1nqkv8aVGH4jkwRvUe1nugKPjWZYjy01wYu2XZRNc5sQAvz648GgJZ2jI8oTnA3Miy2OCNswLWT4P/CEdoOfZM6M7bFkd/pl4/GlC0AEE2ePR3n7z88@bnU7Tm9T2Pj@moC@@eGa8n4y8ZqcpIjbP4eNiLAi66E@mPxYGnZ8bvflBX0KQMxV0Pjm3iMJz4xugTHw6mFD//AsM@gKC5tnNBEL49AG4iZ8nfXg@MZo8KPhQED3HzaZcxiqLTaetUMU1svRoMvUaBZpiPCJBWUIp6bZBeRptqbn1R6MteWNTLq3AU34kr4JzrBTSBcbk9Jksq/XtxiN5c10upR89yqUf6o@YvLktl@TNTVkt36CAVdTrtjLOjisF8Mjnd7AdY8uDJ@gjQpk4tcZD7ZmFq1zMXO5N4rOz8wbgcJsn7pJ7OerDeOiKRAculQ@WNZ9XnoCcKJQd3Otr4evyODWWqi1jaMD47cn1qFQSsDflTqWOCD7iz05OflN9IzdYPN31zQJQ9coxi5s7O/Wrjw1Qqip6eZKC/qC4VR7jc3Mtrk4t9wx/uKxvFkv10XI9pzeWlgofOzvyj6uE@gYyy@J2TBBUZfALWMFFWyicIAbudoBvLidh@KAiykVmCl4Nwc2USjq9WUyn1XQZIi6Bt2A4FWhQIjIIQyiR7SJoZmXPGo5ADyiUb2aS9C5KJJlxCxpiLzF5A7Q58AYQieuMG7qUupFaeKDk2raUupZurm92qkEn/CWbTIxMMN5mDxnrZJal5TRSlV5NDi1rlVrnuFYO3nalVG7VXXNTy8vLUmrntCqvyofaeTiZU83THN0ZztjhHJ12dr6zlPlBMz05rfqYT4lWQZtneeipca9aC68n5Fb5rXVkVIf5qcwP/EAiUgXZVpZlOSWnsN2aPXeE6xx2zniGdr5NkdWeHV23Rw6tCS29wPIzSlxLqTfUb1/aveut1VyV1jEp0IJuqMTMQ5q4l1KOK5xoUx5CK1JAB1@XcbRjscHJ9tvNt1tvX7w6fHW4zx4XSlulLc5wWknxOJvV03oaCvAxdI728Z6UGnx01/VvnS/KqdIgvbqWXk0U2llF7OFVsDYqdZwYqa82GnUYyTRo7Y/eqFSKj/T1rcxaSd9UU1XcTljcRFajC1pobjXVSHEkawDQ4Kvoinqqmhfe@qaupvwcf4Mo6ylfSm29eIe2nuAKPbtIrnyeE7Z8s3MD/9WbOozVbmjIdkP//OfmhofDP4GHb/wRfWKAcZgo/IdVOe081fg2t8P/d/Bn95DnVd6Awkq9q1ShIrw9f3uewrljubiOm7YyeTFs4i0HFa4Vh/4sfwX/3kYeK6AjroRv8LqzwtarOsRayefzZ@qPiqAxbW9vbG2kpN8C125ZAQ6h4ZLItgXDFZC4c9ZE1jz7hYHrRZ1wXSQ4Xow@4J0nj4PLEgPliqF2hYt@Ub2K@wmNK@ZFd4wm/SZ@Hrdtoa8kocumq3tZm6ohitUh7TRiK3iSDe4tV6Vr6QHgGplD2vEFP2VJeoDb/PBVCeCy7KE/VNF4V1ClBw@EePSHmj88R@QYSXjm9LJ0IyF7jFbLZ3TrEE6@8Q3pBu5Zcgf8zLfehPFIPl0MwzXF8O6AGMErrM2pgNysMEqRKMfM8eQfcLDmqI2k7B8834M4MOhu0@pEEVv2mnilF2Vvqa2yUMoDD/BimorgFIEjIKADT64IqH3c9W5Sk2YZpmN4m1Y5AlSW6VmiJMvaImIdXxsQHdG3Qar5gJinrvAcsJVzkazIg6CHMgEsxNxRT0VXxngdMytKD89Nx3ni62CnoIKhbIcV1dhuScIFhcGv4aWIZr8l7heqRGwmbHojC0Vb5lsilRBO@ESMupFWhtl@mRfVoCx9qZiguLieUv62//Ch@XZQ7zfKar8yxGcm04cO9EKxOcjKsNKvQPUY1O1GeVjPZOxGpa9@qeA73gKGva3QunxV5A1y7lSAFlw16qvZD3Un963TyO7XnQyQPMqu/LjyIWtUCqg4Ze2Knu1lvwENhOcD0hxWPmScsrEDX1zpm9itCspCxignvDDKhdKrfKgbDdTEehAxk9mHzACdfr2XyTRUSLwHgbMRy72HD41Mrzou93I5FaHerj7arw/B0chU8L2kGDvjRx/qI4hfUuBZgWR6KhAP8QSvb0Lagb4y8JiXaUQ6p5EUxTGQ169UVn78aOXHK5WlpQ/1ca7fyHL2lwpRbUDix0h8ObYfWFn5scqmWEKz/Yr8mV36TFvBTZ12JgNMzg5iMTmFKz@GkEEmE1B9g/LyND6AxRomNhDy7Zp0IwNtCqEBKw1d@RVEKC5qvmnbApwf6zCw8ZACPM0oS3d3GQSBYeK2Ygw8Gz96JAVJiz1rkDIKFxgqG2gvoDsrcQswHXjB@MFNd8nXeWI4kLnhSJfukYIx9epGrLmSaKIG53tmHUFQDFwXbspcYvGdiiBsSHoADEkPhMuhFEEmCTkhICsiEEorKCCIhXKizQ8do3OXUD7hxWthywcRwsmAxjyHDDv7vkKyCeqTDS5m71B64ICmIj2ATCANmAe7waogyNjDh0y87lSYXtzEvgDBEO59RkegGUoh8XtQCjiQyvdQR1EeUiJA2wMMwW3giYTWfreExBEPCkTIvM/ykx40OulBGTk@PxkF@aZyMrAsHjx4n6msCYLgn0YOEB/Cbn6bEt19ie0evjh6dbp3/KJ2Ar8wTtyKX88X3Jw7c2/mAO/DbNoO7SY1jWPd@voLkzEFx0p4vQJejN1iX7x6zorFl0@zeOgxsD7FjfHQoZZCTJZPl8/4mut18lf2hZ3fS5xKincY08ZVv0RX1oqVrRYdtkB3YYfntUTHtfhou4POXJzUmrjjrG/5vrgONBdcrU7H5NHJNX08gAVaobg@lPYEJbbg40KQLG3N8uyOTfdldzmCRHy6B2zIo1P7kPDaTxqzQo2WtrcKhRIrZNGhB45i4FgNHGuBYz1wbASOzcCxFTi2hUMPMOscM4xrV1c3Iudm5NyKnNuhc60QOSMMa8XIuRo51yLneuSMUlsLU9vYIrwsFXCTmq7lYZi@thWEkTlgSJ7rgEaf9lwDQoszkBB9bcYT0ttKem5uF0RCB/lDBCoWN6J3kD4BbEXhVGU5HVmeMn8TntBXSXyYRxV2z/NAKu2N8Z5jqHRqieFJC5KE56mZPcsAZcAagpZS2Yf6b6kl6oOG3qQUHTOBGCp6@A7R8ZY4iKPTVd28@swJLs4L5tiKc7Hx47VYyJjYgRuCSE5lKdHTcoxrCb841iUUsMjRBRBFDoFlkDyfI0jz1BvNTXL19iQTCOcmOUMUx7s@LxbyRiHklSAq9f@ErRKkx/UUi0ob1ACMCYVOdWCqQPGgrsq1XpJ/890v/2f2m@9@/mv2/Z/9@v/59/89uv8d/vyveBBFMQT42c8ZLT@Bn3/BaLEJLXyJIhH8akn@/pe/gtf/7t@w73/6cx70x38uZ9dCRBCCXlHMX/wT/Pl9/Pnf5ex6CPiLP@SAGEXO3kgJ1UoBqJ/9FWOQGmIJkf3yLxiTM6BgKKLm1Xkbb8QO5eEIQjbUydWYDue/eL0t8LigZmTAK9706C2DBaDGkHsGnv0WtT1QZ7jJEaW0aZhdPN9CeLk@6j8mqjCur3Wgvl21QOkRZok05P73WImlMwiDFhY8l6zCZbjIv8i3HIUibEbOA3V4w6NARZf/hpTA8FaC@k0jgYmv4bCFRqQ6ryOCvy8t6CaCDkQOahZdZiqJtILYaJYR98LT7bbBUBcrLXZD/FwvutRVEgcw6LEEE@JmqtgglWkfGDJGJ/PEo5KH1R/gyTKViN/IWHwhLmSn0UUlJ5rN3uH@VIPBTxNUzIu4RAoTqjBZvgMWOS3gVdS4VpPwnF4BUC@UVhuJM37mActfffWVLMX8CliHvJZCGGKZ4iIjDNKTQcVYUDEWZLcFTpI168XiFA3UcaBcTJ50xaPFRFQyWlS5sOUE5YBkwFiQG0Sz7d7I71ZmUZNETgq7WeQxlHqjItrJmUMyp8pkdSYC4EzGqUyX5XzUhRmY2YKaHxO5nfBJlNZiTIk4sUZB3JOmuRSWnL49r@SSCd6CWm9k7plQsfA7JpS7Z0Ib63cnNF2sGDeBfjF/7xY7gZgIJXyEjDf8VKKDwq7xl1D1InGEFHvkVFQY8tTEkKd55TIlGH507GF31KRhDPjng1sO8s2e28z3cZTj4c0m4d0HOIjBI5u4eeDxwIUhh4tacDBUMhz2SoAnhh38XuWO43qWHz88SVy17KTxTCvT7TjQq2XxtgX7whIXblviBNRkvxL2bEILxfOsYeiDqDmjUPM8P7cde3h@Dspnr61GDMRXzcQ9/2nJhIjgisVXQtX2cKC4eGvMUL0bJ@m7PNqpbV4ohwMRmIZEagwGdKbVg8EX6@Lt5MFV05hFfl85aKTNoUInO3fdvtuxHBeP88LYU@gPItxIkDEYEC1ZZmSZGaNIDKIVM2uoIuqXnxyVfVlUDDWMX0wiSDAjy7xpHiNnvTnJnS9MjkcL0jv5dHpP4vSe3E5v2/b84TTN5InWHnx@WtKrSoQBACMyVu8mIyuO0ZwhJ0FK6O2jXkQR7k1iixZEtZDSGoDWBLjWhvqRDd982t0vCH@9iP@3F2AQfe@@xUfK7MkE5E2fLrKnIZofTI4rAH6gqtGCyVhyYdV@es@0xECHRnhZJpPgcvDoCGiYg4HlRDeJB4jvqPO4rGmm3tNapwoPnEOTd5llF8XFRfT0vGX1jInVUgRkNoY3yPGxZbRIXt0v4yjoSOjBGIAMmYWsnlDF6IgfAiotqDJG9lJVF1crDmKHtYcm44jCg8X8I8PdtGhGI2iFz4G4HkjQFJ1PS8cJDyaDCT8WrEfn9QVylPc/vCRfuuJAwFsZAnwgs7aiZ6Nk1dvE57ESZukePUIIqyWzTIdrBN2WC9r4TBl@GovuzilZGcJIlaCUE9rJohK3byvxWK0I6iTXSu5XJe@qdPeuc7GqxpFFImz307qQGcy7Rq9nmkocI/e5tcRcZ0YmoB@WmOss6FXO5wjUMCZJuiHehlvh@oUq2eA8gOclPF/DExHCGPScV6ggb6jXBiYvCukbg5jWInzqJuqiMS6q8XnEGJQUuNGQexOmaS5M05xJ00ykGbaAZJIxIMlMJClKAYvntiLoWe3hAumMQThyh8dtYhs@jmt4OPd6nbbTJTvL0pfpEgjktJUu7SkglNOtdOkpOfx06YQcF@nSl@CI2lb6Y7oUNAsE8OCVHI/RX4hwfDfTpV1FvZGGeDh3kK6WLoVlCjCP@Ctx5IabV5ti1t8NraqWleVKZZZhjfHh4WK26o0sfQvwzw/f5afFQ@BShRVXCBgHIIlOI9Zj8HSg29B67pXlKfO6j1JgmhL2jciGAuGZSsyogrVkRPIonUonhREnDEPJ@AhPIBDlZmk@RUyfGZndRY5IHWooFXIyfeKeRvpAS6HwOgDHjTi9KH5QXkkUvADvRydGXkTnDDlBckQRLgZQ55CFTH2XviVTWNZT54fz0o@X0KyNAAsxF4DwUiK0MZkOOhzqppTYwB0kKwmF4myfHY@DH9EosfZORSOpIFrmgmDyFjlDwRBv/Opt2YnFQ9ISIggD64UGb2Vhv0CyGIMiWRfTVHnjAxJiMqdF5yZaWG2fCifBcXGTpb5iUTcUxOVJkuRKikmIrOHG@ZEx5KlH8zK4nf7Thq9BzDFeKKMggljMMBUuX91P0N9drr8HCnXAhKkE5inW87vSWfX61l52ivJelOxsAWJglj1V5ypHYQoRy2F0ENPMb6trMyr@yAmUfJ5oiH1K2w/YFo4J7uDb9NiC40ItwbtMel6gYfaiuJhRsxpJ71ILlBYNUxJ4eMZDSqOs3U4rz/i8IsYQ7KPh8ckF7CULOF54iI8y4E2xnLdy3PJF8xRh26bT76KZCz7r4OIqsfDE@5gniHtavxYu0QKPw/Pjp4cvn38Nne7m5qY6OxWBrRbiRv24dOs0QThsKWbx3Fjcs0drJ7quN1w6c@TZJWXkAcqAQfM2vPqJNq4KWRaT51NtF@Jx2BhHBa6LqBkYCamEqo6BXbYt@Mpv4VRWDIEkUG@B31kareGsEdYOnNA5P6fu6/wcF@ecn4teDIsmnEb6bYqJMxOlVHINE@lZ/syRjDjsH/Vpi1RgdhOHLfLVJ3gA2sEwiB3GGjlDO1jigFYh2pMZzOArqzraJA7aoQ/RgUsxlOIaDlyL63j6CI@F0GjupAWVIp0lrt7gNTr@wHXo1Hg6iZeUdbzUxw8MrkT2yLkyaPEHT4UOTYlRxJdhBbNhrsNvuPF5XNwMSobjgDdZZnU0mucpbsNA48Ie8MPEwwUfvkqRiGBamQU8bvasPpB0AjV2jg35hQ2VprtvdzpQffLiQlm@rOXUgKg5t53bDQ7JTLHXRs8Obw0RK8Ho9h9h/QV2KolTTn1W3AAdajsLnI2@wFhcHMPwJNMCLc0iKPhuwmOTO7eysbhLykSdfa7qS8o5lijffG97eGnspeHE@Eufj3FDtJiipFYfm6cE5jricMQ0no4YHrApiZOWKzRNqeEStYEip@Tg5E10SgPPQnGd0/n6CaNnBkeCKngYbUl64JAEwqVgzOSLbEDTdVB7o3k2NVyb6rDP2GpRoquQXLIycwIAB5/iS2CHMIiK@eDL/ISkkT9ryZ/hrKL0IIVCkVc/jB/UbnTTLRdR9WZLAh2udxVTmLxZBC/rsRdsHfzyIsg6jkY2gMI5lCwpcgbQZmRV5qjD@NPRxTTJAy6iZzFlcabugWA1YPntJ6/ftjzPITDp0oWK3Hfx@Fm@9rh8y2pgWg6Maw4Ti4GR6PjqzrZY9MYv38zKr3DZVoknQh2Ohscxo7wvTwv8nB6s8aQHLq5mK7SluZ3onWQPI4dkLNnObQRQN0QVHcUUrRn7zC/BF2jIBiiBTbTMQSHeqHfSRhzBxdd0FlujHOuHFD1ODRLY9kEetYGfWZnuL3kIEalfhk5SnadrFcqJ@ECcP3Bo@bec02SKKpYqI6YkCl6a6B8umJVolXwg9265YMLI61uFjW1adM2c7DDbr283sitmRWbW0Dacvj/yrloXHbd7CRoGG7xvjs3Jh28YW19juDOl@JCfG6BvVHAjiMI26eSN7QLtCQnO/aDTJ85kxmj7MJ4ikmYs3KVUXsLDA@CTxZ@SXJ6ppWylH9RCvvK6X99oVJxKodyvO42yk8mow0xlmNEzCno81NUyCGpuq6kPG7SUMr/CXgTrHfH4ZTTIum125Dpm1037jK7wjk8E0p6woAH1jUG8PV3CUMX14j5trE9GP9EQZ73o@supmLYbwA0nAwvFaLhUtOdC/cWfB6ONtfJsOObwwQNc11wWCm08A9fSYNTs2SaIJ@In6iW4xrFUEiv1TYb1FmQX@tnck9MCHZiCweUg1HQHExHZ5iDnQV52YiirCnZ9avY@kAFUE@rkOV6W4QEYB@HsTYAzQE09mMqpQvdzywl7J9xcoZZx6TlbCsKCbRgIj/WGNkOcg85IWyfgscMEKC1MZqpYBky@dRtXIpB@V03zoAfvR/0BqQcap1dwBO@oOx8YthfG1PwR3mapMB2ZYQdEYwmg4wY3812CNhovmqAs0BpBM@KYH8R3RMe5A8GmgTchg2zEGSHE13IpzgN@e6ICHSa3dnEyRFzKhiqKGhiHJ@qlB@kSI@NEGbyo@ynHQt9DKOZ1QXAfgvvGsLsguIu4R/6iYA@C8U7FBcE2BPOFKvPDXQjnitgCgCGa3qC6ng/d86Fh9xS@yhrXZ99wga2wTCZgbFgFGC8YXh7J@EysV2dLvHR4ZUtUL2ifVK04AFZpRTQefI9qC4XiUR8KrxexNDlP2DW7MzFhsQIWn1NKIHYxfXUlgZ/FCID2B6KUzYYHifPSDjOaqD8av1cLgndA5n/8eBtloiIm65/eCGofLyE0jsZyyLkV4eGXs0XlyiN9EJHmxxHr@ePSLdBco3wEjbIYiRDetqJ23bZBt4SoKmo5kTeOQ1X2KPKp@w1WCqVHxEfeLO7mY3Gm9uAwlVpkljUjp3l/rhpY7yGmAT1yMxIWuHnLKM@w0w@hc0noKkCH3JyqZ2aizohW@qmZvV9uUkAfNWriTZkLWhNUw6ogcA55Bi/XuEzgyJbTJe6Pt3nZSWT2AmR8k@M5IBjuAA3YswViPOgTbUfjC4VAzheKa1my@3OQm4hNgbC6D5/@HhoXMk502SO84CQpktgc1syAh/lGflWnm9xU9rikn5@5Ol9pln6URhrZbH2iWvcIeskSK7BwN02Z3dwth34YZ66j4kvoO76yWFYEhR7UxPtUwZsFjL6zkiWzUGywBMeRBJIMd3RJtDN0fqcUzXecBz6BLYy37YUaGFJVToYjzRxhEACKcjxWVuhc1Uh0ii2x58NAuclGWhjeK8ZrBajsZSkuznE4t0@dd9w33M9DHImH4PJC1DC9gDK7Hei2oAYH8TTzHIuZMxn5CW2647otJVCYhMJAGIJl0wCU5XuMQrWKq5dR8pCcUHpZRyy9DvrdMvgsCS/qV8p0R3ugnyERKx1qNmVsNjH9xvbp2jsKx94IkgqmhNCWxKUPK037I3SoAj2YGymQ@LhRjLYTCzlPPXFCPMi7hoN2OzqIjIbWOzL6hwWBMFUYaEebjqkMbuZYGfjGarHl@Do@dLHLtoY6cVjoYtQOw/SQmp0dGZOJztP4bWopP/K9fNN28pZzyfDKeCkVmrdKeLVobgutt3hBqJAmZCwngxBUEygpTE1zrCslvHAUbQ8S3yhIBiRdwmMlyJjfsy5boPXzZfQD1x/T7wQGCwVtNBi6FCISog2F7KP9MdrkXqCpXTFiEOTsEJ4IRsFJH@474XarnM4VJB2PzFBjKOoYkwSufCbLWH5IqDD71RuSr1mG2UUisO595MMpKC6qyTeSHxQ9boBDVuCMIjh7fOnvgOx4mARpJ/6E3iH7@K6jg/uQJRLrvRinSGSvxRC8ARwrOZrlMP4OMIAz/sHJ6dO942ONW@O4/aaEUw/czIzrNmgXobhKXFhZcQoB93DyQnmAmUXcPL1KhJzkL/EIkxVswqZwhezkvMJNojwHOZ3eZrIRwqscnFhCc9DizUdeFsRS6wHoUci7KJoSi5YLogXAMVY8uJMbhmni6twXVt8FinetXg@I5rx4ELEDnciRIP1MmL5fxzQbIfE8PDcTnkuEazycExVBaWbXi4BKcSA5dR3B3TA5AsvOpFVhkOmDl7TlR3O9GN3l22B9DQZpdgRcDYuS18owYCcRkIuFvJ1T@jxkKREnrOBheJ2Hi/pdFCUfUpmAfZxMH5@SKCCLFsaKdSRTtVRz7N4jbn4MQ0jCMtzrwqNjeVO1441SGESEOMmBmMBb4bHZVisRloweSBxqM3J157GsCZPUI2WaDG7wnmlYc9pIjEuUZoYYN6aeBNKh4KUYCsKJFY0FLbcaRJ6IyJMYWoRaCpKVgu3byQYOWZtu4hU0oX/En6CxJ4kL4FLzAx9wysc883wiLMkgErpL8nw2JaXJ0BtZ3FNk6pZeJEp7Mo1xvpB46eII1OyipAjTtPh0XdsdOa2lUE7EBUUgKWb4HoYITkcAelB9FxUhBt5Iv82vSJ8bfdAKe9aY1VCnNuigJSkxF4pXhft4phgeksn80WDQs8VmO3ZFs23iKKLiOk4MRRhjSoMmHeCqHQ6fRZeYu4RIGjtEzFc2v5JbBPijToffr8zwAkcQrXhruj3UpJoz4Vc/4960Ip@RFJe2owDuwbAvRgQvOd56wuu0NSk4gYdntc3bt7gLHGfl8F5n6NJKkvSjkW1e7H7OioXCpl5Y1WMsC0zVBW11jW6QDlSkIKBY0AuFdX1NknbdwYSvN1FMFXGt5RBhlj3Hjv411E2879yxpBr0GATo4/XslndptTRJOrZaZANujogjWJXpBnMn2HyPPqBb4SFEeAe5n@UXjUMNwyf2z/xAAZNWO2clnOIdWF7fHvKJYPfSxqvRw2ntttvruVdkiMYZZc4PjNS3hsCUFZUlSaLDAgQtpLvQHn7ghiHugTaa7iUd7iHYAHqqjWci0fyshDtbEUM8MX6JbIwSSM/sGXYfq9McAnDrS8SBgADIWmtkWrfSIBERn0hDcMF1yzVHeFyCEZRMHqSfS20Fmrvl2SB9IwZTqVC0GO1QwKfPDk7YyeH@6Zva8R4D99Hx4euDp3tP2ZOv2emzPbZ7ePQ1nSLLnh0@B@lywmovn4Lvy9PjgyevTg/BQ66dQEyZAqTay6/Z3ldHx3snJ@zwmB28OHp@ANgA/XHt5enB3kmWHbzcff4KOuvPswwwsJeHp@z5wYuDUwA7PcxSqkE0KYrHDvfZi73j3WfwWnty8Pzg9GtKcf/g9CUmtg@p1dhR7fj0YPfV89oxO3p1fHR4sscwY9LTg5Pd57WDF3tPNUgf0mR7r/denrKTZ7Xnz6cyevjm5d4xEp/I5ZM9oLL25PkepUT5fHpwvLd7ihmKXLvAPCDweZadHO3tHqBj76s9yE7t@OusQHqy96NXAASB7GntRe1zyJyk3MEVKJfdV8d7L5Bo4MTJqycnpwenr0732OeHh0@J1yd7x68PdvdOykx6fnhCDHt1spdleJULJQ04gFsQDu4nr04OiG8HL0@hz3h1dHpw@FKFQn4DjAEqaxD1KTH48CXPLTDp8PhrxIp8oALIsjfP9sD/GHlK3KohF06Aa7uncTBIEJh4Gs8me7n3@fODz/de7u5h8CGieXNwsqdCgR2cIADgxHTf1CDRV5RrLCegizuhskpBzc1ScbKDfVZ7@voAKRfQUANODkRtIbbtPhM81/Ds2rlTbrdO4M3O8glTyO0n9@wePt0DjY8f6CdH/q@g09lKTt4lwqCjCQPhVcyCUl913rKao8657bRdHJqH0fgMdt/vZPGkSpUpeP/OLSfCi4lyipBKnZ@/rp3DOPfk/FzN3idmgoy7Yoit8bdBqSKPPddo0TA/YVuKM6r6UBzAk@WnYcRtLQ9D44PK8vmWJaLhQhJEHJiJxElRgKyFkpFWmBgOiyVJU8xJWxEdYzZtLAqmN10ffpyP0QvvG2IeIJz5uoV8HsewRAYeR8dC@iEROqlNHNdG6wDsNiWp@ZZ10VEK8eRwyC8MVGoQh2CHMAzsKOod0ZtWZyp6bjo@EYsrgEhZCc7oCc7O4Tdv45tgGRPlonmUM4Wb9uihBtRQQqAUqjwpWl4kVp8oD3l03PTNbYVqOTzfhc5oe1H76uANDuYKxbXylP@z0J@3LVwKiAcOQn9Xp3gNejxrcABoYDYOv4Al9oRPqebzsTiglZE@GQLjAUJdBLqyW9CnYlfdtahbx2OL@BkO8fjQGXv2OE49iOHPj2svnrza3wfJidSuba1vbpQlcQySN/wqy59fYzp0qC5yF7ToKxvUNAqKtZJd0Hv2Z04wjB25iKWHgHhqeVBo5Ik3j4fbmbmOwA8942YgzK6Pxz45ePKZjCc3eTLDRZPWkhTU17ktU1QAJZFVFXPTN8ak4RugKlEdMPnW5d6ESm2MP4g7bP5BEw8zJCqQqGJWfzCcQM2FwQXJPXk/WAVKYxta4oUgmhzU44ERrEHijEGZSUtjcYkkvYm6HStF0GuxoLG9UrFTTCBiaZqK4OQ8OgcTkjhy/aAFc08bfL4S9Q2cX4sTGzEIz9@qDU@AjfthzFxwoiK3OYuGITA3qhUooocPw5R2GBpSVUEUt/8nz/OLtwYihS9oYFOIg5VHIZ/DEDJCP06r7JrXVDxqBfGURY0V71Bz52VHYCkH59SI9@BYP8ZxRaf8kddVmIYUgHwdgITsTLDpd@IH4f8vyJM5@HdgwAnYI26RHLadkXVPThJWzisYvRJT7KtgxVhsmVrEzbjX1xGam3jBdMOMiWV4Yz6xBCwQpTMJPL7m57wqcxiAlRztGvH2i6cqUCPuGjByekxt9wGf6fccsz9QglNSg65iBm8jSzpXNlgihy8qn8IvsFhyz/HQu8e0@ZZkBg64QIo1J@wzX@Y4MjrJHMx0foWMHmErp6qJbNCDFh5Vp4JoWkHjH4sVRlEv0wpCb0AVXXwCazgdggc9JgR@MAMSCBBa@xTPsGAbpFlFQufmG5ffk5WfiV7cQrHZ5v0yO6XV077RpjEzdkViqTOuqcYkEc9nLXGQZtMaXmF30ePYaYl3hI0pn9Eqc0xE2CJDNSIQvqoGXKdO9iqknsyUWF9D6l85Fw5e2GFxE1cAoSWO5Yzvi9fYC4NO6OzdL99ylHgG2VpNpn/g0LJ3k89XommORu6QCo70P/MjjoDGeYXaJfRDEZcM8wI95aCO2lc5ewwPSisnch4cNAljBjpGeJ7Sf7NwQIB1ZWoNLJPPnNCIVOIdWeWzQH1BF2@7oetrdAk7cwUyBcSBDy6YFWoQkox6Ey7SnG1tRF@416EopWjxaQk0p6srrWmM@obTNvp2b0KrTt@7XSfvOyN/oA0meH9o0hpIF5IAHNA@tNgb22m5Vz57As0BDUknL1@dHCUNfzHL1y63fDH2BaTBnlDK0gz6Nm5k8d32EIrGKrOJuILKi8w9ZCcUlhYya03QA3cLeVSBIN1@qBl//vIV@9xyLA/0wSNac8me26blgPgAZYpWYfpdLmkQfB9TPxGps33UXciyU2aWTUad0LYniQQEtixWLQWaIhDsibOu0TY/gaoeswlqsxmO8tUKjEpddyA2a6DRFJVNbuJsj3pZCQ/UfnNw@gwH43xgTrYZ6NYCWx/aErnq1OfGWsiMZzjDCTBFmjbeANl32W40Rns1AKO0mJ00qOvjtT8tNPv1fMgq3h8mpAD1INBULfsST/AlM9x9yojW2QqzWcS3stj0mhWX4AjRkSg9KSq9LB7krmXZ@jY7tbDusqOeYcIIi52MMPrqKuiBT1x/iKAvaowVirqu5/RVNNG@Oqlp1BDwGxzrKkkHL44Oj0@BkeLcoqBihH0mMp9OUuWrsYAdOTxPFXL/DgVyAA8Ss/iOmIcqeHC4glzmMxZySYayNw0090IO/aQ6TCZZNMm7Hp3mipt1oAolmiOk6l@h8OVTI5RSDHuWzpMVJ8LyriWkk7ZYUoR3SFsP6lUP50PfUWTyAwFgjckPYnk0MmiJs4igTPpWP6TeHga9u8EBpOmDaEOGcVsqVI50No1aEnBPjeNpWbhGwscjnfr@pemBbDEuocrhEpZgxxLUGZJNapgbo2n3bGgDQJfZdbHD4eIqKAgyQcSPqZWoxMMDELFDIlrmHCEFravl9kNQTpUkhTv0hP/An5guS3VgmI0jLX9gWS06vmo04OczYbgGrbwHPQffu1eKDm6SUgVaN@mBsMFz8kD2jXq4oR83YDZ5mUtBbqBWBXs@T7s4rOeIIEcnQ2qkeIyuMmeEnWU4z6tSsRtQITCuioxYsPsSUAyyOCkFVEF5U4UgF1WXLF1bReU9vTkTI9IJkf4gGYC4@KyulQwI0GPehXMGgFfSSkjA1L7PgBi@Z4m7Ezaw5AvmF9ed4p42hecRMjdRQ2bu23iuObcNuKzj4i8CawHH@ByhRXOEM7tJ8UZQHfBNQ@qzkAAVnuoWgyzOwZmbi3N1Ps6cwCkmKw@cS9pPh7GoWvBc8CM6XJCPyIgo@5@7geilXX89l08whbnv9NwmHqYJkgJSw8ckGxVs3JtGYAlGx0P5zs7kIaA7QZYE6WJvU6C7sB1oH1aV7QQWi@qZwwtKBFR4W6LtY4z6LmpO5MQf0aLIKSdOFEWtY@pIUSSP@4LsRrSyQCl85BKLWiauxInDi5STUfqJKPpUFEFcMkozEaUoRdvHp0oXY6Dox2cyZ4FeQquSqARYJSyggtQ3xnx0U6DNgGSmwXO8ExsXiw1RQRCwbrJwfyGCN6To3IzEtD1PI3ilJXi04ltelukc0kLyEKpxsHSPxABBJcIndDaLo4gMqYIN9BKeyaEGxIh87VAUJyapwgzzACmRbQ/3ainxVNQSSw0MPmuIUD52bPGk68QDnKWX4W@FKSKBXJxYDoRnHQhRCIyn8zDqMJTlxRLIwYIU9cz0FhNwUIISl9@0ZIx3A4qSaFeB5A5xcueM7AZU6M/RUUoS35Ttg17HfbFHiYmGE1T48Gx5oeRZYxie0RwzoaD@J7RYC09@0EQoPQTx9SjlRtBrJHOxEHq6K5kHE@tVQi7cBhwwO@TTQuDFvQ2xDm0IKO84eIx1z9FILFgXdMFpn7OMtBR7SHvRXdPmEirJtpjQ5XGzcwRwssgD4rJTuZJi58uIHE53I1Ki50xUEiX2hnfnsM/46cIckSolYiH/FxU4LneMN@yFcDqHE8W@qEaEuIJyv61ahMBBud9WLThwrNhvrxbBAdMhayn@dL1IlARnAS5KFCMGsinFZVAQMI5DjaegiKBJI37AjNVT5lAbk6rC1inNqEohi8R5csk06DHmBSOuLUtWR2BePSyNRpRb6OPMC6sVHpMhch8OkapyskvgpTl9OhRmOkiByqih4j0mYQSQ2NwIJsbMfb52k44ZSvMBC41B8SjVTje5uzeBNuhVCuqsQhkcqRQRvzOX@Nzs0VbREKs0e2lPuLpMUI0LnlyvhdCyNGfGV7qDqkyMqmTuYiWUZPECTLl7YcrdA1M@hkk07FXoL8mZ8vDwYOsuFGdnszjo8RYGUgIHSNqWjUZsHAdfGZO7cC6BspWiNXUGX1UWRoj05LtwPJrGQYe1d8PZOOHZNdDq9sHy3Omj0hZyNllX5lAUUpWaJSuLZJHUpvGugAtUJRrbahfNrh2OBFJ3lzQ/U0JExqXE3XASKJU86ihEFrV/fQH/srFiTbYHTnjCDAPasvSJzUFDRnALE98qFkaICbLkOFQEJBlxe@i08KPR6vRJE3gK/cJo6p05ecwNPjGjkw5Z4xIrUeOCIVwknILeKpBv84Znd6afmpv@wB2AjtOeSwDB99GOz41SUyI9Uk2nhtb36svm9mez@YrrbVMHxt2/kT@cyXoRso4b06FRO9aV6P1vwyzyEpTAD9Dk60EdWUDkZ3OJxIl2Qxi3mDPqNy1Puk9T5zE0fPAx0uKaK0mpFKuZMGQWBxfRtVF0prIlkkQ1GCuCz0YDnK/x@eJObNxoI7N4BZ6GxZvkCVqTMQmy0fYtwxEnGYkOs@Ph/EUIm8Uz1XFzF6VgOyYw2rdi5s93/KKQliVCcEXyLWwtzy97rNV00z2nIhulJMjiuqYySY5pue8CBSfUagiqNK2oBHUHJ0NXuGYu9CVQzNX5JrD7aE@3KURQiRclKQa8U6hvr6OlxcwcDUJWhkVzD1bOU7dCK/c91K3JfdWt/wKcnC5QKeYW2oPoYEt3CrXpQT7dkhuclt2fc3TL69P9/cSBJ81JMCroW956oVDAQ3BmrsTDCQqcJbbdfBI6jzbx/ODqC@91M49Rk5fgzb0DD2kAUITGqQmsJzg1MYL@JnYqF9pzHNyV897nkPwEnhajZZx2uLj99SlVPkKJzLNK7B1mEPP3jgV3VIPiyIcMAkuw3gxioxp6KQfL5IA96NHGE3XCJWmEjMbNYtcCTnxUqtfSA3EvJNn58A4f9Trahig/s3o9N8veuF6vtSTz3aHJCPv78QgFDoJLCXnj8elOiSyzLu1e7F4NBIndys4vZsJLd7n1k/YyedYAZ9IU7MeOrc7eeKDI9bcyVEzIcgazmWFyA7f3dGToomSaQr8bLT/GDMi@F3TfGCgm8WkaGPpAsZcqcgFFq3jzJl8djPaUXcgyLuZQEiAqPxeG8@xuaGTqfHK1967tKJB1DJZwuxxt/abipZwsAA@ZK5@N9TbysMBxCJrw3MT7xbgp46FTP/yD1m20HODmRrLxhltiY@eNxfMRGOOxZbHLYbsNzYtb4qvBUWMBOhKVOZ1WKSBrRMF61jcj0GeUdNsXx97hUpuTiWMmCKkXG1kmDscr/255lIIWKJof8BOXTXyZg2a9P6LLVSJ5RmY4XEAxK3cwwjlGkKTPzMo3V0qtVmPLg0yG1WpPwJHLsdqTGnuKHk@esKfw/gTfH1aK6@tlvnLuqXoNnk8Czxv2BHBQF4QXuT2FVwij@5lwKIVFvJyvLGfLy@eVnWrZz9drTxr5fAdcf/t7P/3bf/zH@Zp4@Q5fntBL/W0IpGlaftm8Xn54U8b3@tNGerlZXx400p0y1jIU96883@gZsW1imvn3cplusHPeVBlotGqlkmbpjx@562wYOb3IiTcfRNGN3qBrUHRGGKqVdC398CG4dirpH6dVPLlD@Buh/wfwZyrKcpovJtbS9HHtZPfgIH65UHhpaRs1TZxwN8TiNNvxbcjUu/@3vavtbePIwZ@tXzHeRaKXSJbkpI7zYhVp7w7IAdcCbYF@kAJJlleuAFnaateJhZzutx/5kPOyq01sB7leWuRD4pW088bhkA85HE5sd887Q3N0ZN50zMR1jwO6x/JisYumzhGj0pn/aCft6BB9jyhVNCzhpwgwkrgniUa7yi4RXmQDlPAbgsG40IOL5xI6hzoekcDj91/IodSGLDcePnWXY93OOsP@yTdvOnEco2VE545nEHNoLfX3G8@CYFlEuklGvZSWDI2da@MuDw1VyMSI4wcz6sfDmeZxWOFCSR4w8hXW43qQGsNQlxK5ivDA3d9rgDb0ZBlrWPSOlPk1jlszNtjeNXCPOuCuTTfvDa70jeSm2m1wg2BwezBnPClfLe8SdPrL5XG3vK1wVsrEUK5QiEfWPTjoTMdoPxPc2GeqiV7xY57YnSU9cb9ebi@XfOMmDk1k70g6EeWbOlnLlc2KyC1IyfNkzhufsqJlwvyhPQDDhM/Crma8u8BJSJeceVcAn71rmRAkrQdGOJqHY85nvhvLlRwVWM/pkRQ@J0SUO6XBho@Q3EkYijfVkCJGyls50EoJu6byJlOVPvswW7AHB3lrgMbBfsBl2tSS2NBTTkuHHNHXf2NvAGjqSoqwVlzIDqHKKzZB2SlCROE3j5CwlkTD1kyWq0nVXdOIUkST0syxRCKTxHLNLHTjFc3Jod@oKaPh9Laraa7kTddZttBAFZ0mROHIKeEN1Tqq16Qx5ZbwNu5W6lZUOD7LSskN8Tn7wSTnCLVOg1QuKLzIwZsceShxcXEhHhdXsrPIPU/yxUyOSknrh1YWp0gHwt9K3pQPNkTGg4SD2glGCyOjp1A1EhRT7esBnfhUMq//3xz0noJmNsRI@muztqRDxxxudkaeSL5GxwmooEgU7SOcU0rBgwJjLpPLRV4o05ZD13q@VEaxs6TnRT5BxGNA3RJlOTbIXoftRMJE6W2DsFnw2t9I0J5KdHU179nBsFaTWCxXUoaExBmn@/zh5JHtTthrWsFEPl6@7eIMQbmyrltkwscyJ55VjZ@Fj7aAyrWLIi9aOMmPClRalGnSGfKlwCVqkDgtLQMvhXuF6gMGZuYONTlkVIm8Ml0CCfaEt@UX29NdxSX3/8t2C1N5vuFUs7T46C3mA9LRPpj8nN5YzTy6cVVWrsB3iQXqLH4XOL@0uV4S8pcgddUo4T3yvlHXj1JTdug6wx0gpdQmLBvWw7ksFbXj9aXfFEt36pK74b3N4NAIkE7a1MQO@uuBKHPSprZeSc3Q6NmPO5tDQlMwuMh0OztKcqjX6ZzJw7HuLM395OyqWMPa8FbK2zErsuDQmLBy1IXcQ/peGO9fQaQdXDivrvP16/zzY3r47tCbxdx9ibvqCRdMCQYrRJg2u/pEj0Pce/2ZzAKWAwsSBHJSZZol9FyrCfJQCzP6V3b53fqm0WuPolHU7p88a0awkx0Oi2cZWUbxLOGI6g1bCYnanqSJNULubSIifHO@uLggxKE3LlBRbc39NNZqh@whf@/EXdaBqo0gxJMokOVZhyYRXyit8ZxuppdXUzz@sP5lM92@JiWEjz@uZD5/5vp@ImXEN6/il59kjb66IKgR7dhO9jxxpyHCZT4l5DPLAQ3yRFIlOLhQQYBkjwDSpht/VhxsQIZw/OK7cOgZepMmdSIIJZPY8InkBJzABODjCWSnjeU74k01YTLks5NH/CQGQRlA8g/2JE/wrZQQqL80Ay5TSOnnM6qB8RpoTUq1zZIYtGdNro8PZS0nHyeu99lEDZt89tv46nqZL3Rke8Oy4@JCbSOkuOZrSXSYnEWQs@EtzvgA1Ev8iPTKFqOzy7BMu2AcXO9wQavU2zIQVJ4KaoTZWgL70ZIb44fb0YMGNVUkg/vxE/BHb/fiI3Mj6H5gTQ1OsM5J3ILpwHiZ5oG5IRkHnZ41btSHBeOD@0FE4W60UpbJIpp34RzzDHMKeAgTN7l/hM3@ZzZy5Rsm2dhTydqlGkYtMszb@jg/3Da9DnYLQquWOAWFs/WVjbZUcyIwXoO7oWkF8Qny/7fBeovlVkB/Aans@cwQuxwWFloBHNqDcQE5HYiBZg5nAWMNwUiIJCByUs2AJnSOgqSVrOsrxIYYJfSm9LkMsi1iciOtEG9UxZ7ybDsYsfdT06I3h4DwKvHUhRWqqt28YtPNYPbqeQ1m@1rElCFkN16BesxaYYQ7NriVUMk@ofqfRijpVxWd5JfPRqYiAYpU2tVqVezrRIceGA3XussVsCeXQLhDB4RLdVQAXexrBh0rV0cTaJH9MwuGW@bVJYnFIhaWqIGp/06sHjEgs1JuKOeIkyM115vkOSFiQlc1@keQl6UUzscVPCAEWbs19xIyQTA1QG/njdDcZKYbN2u6M9uVUKJG/2m/iUbu0FKtcG/GveG9iEHeipnvpblghQLI0TJjTRVyu/aDrvuAW7owvkqXNElk75QW8dxKUz6ye5uXuhvbG7YMVW@a5hMd1PCVHIsOYj9PN64dUBcEaXDAFjWG0o/UwZslNIzUHpkRd65P/CH2oXV0f0n@b0vjDCn5HQc4gNCz6IDxGdeqE6wIAaGEWKD1B1mdSO0OzFe24qEa4CJIW@Bkq8H7qqorHUJuVqClM@tTBNQOvIqVXlPrITJxZTHTkPO90yW2jpIZO8KdlyprBv5gdTt06zZbNHdLUqK4KgviKhzOw4dG@waXdQljVBr6BUJJPwrEGK1EOJdZl4QQfwnCq0qhZeJQX1rpf5AX9A2/Oh9WAxEWrx6HeA9N19P9euUoX00dFP0YfXhAl@tSKgHQRO6vs0kefW9q9yVomZ63MCkcen8eLr3XTNyVVV2i9GpeFF38tC@6ONQ926zL3gbWPpKPXzL6IIWM1z@mFaZZOhD9CzcF/ScMyvd2TXOXLoykfZZL5GjTB3lk@VGWQ3298NuPbMeJTppeXJA6vubT@NucquCD@LipLqCzFMpgUtxPYVojXZpXUUgmJnelbJlpaW@XGRhmgflr84@BUnNN2HRA1SG8CDlbeOtqPZMMYBwEyM4BxJXCru2LWcQGkRQc8kdNpHIwl3zkc13JMgLTGmuzOgbtDwYhGOu7zTS/E8TyW3Jyut2sOBss3zVQ4sPsqMZ3bt4Xkt0Fl7XujMviFnzaLQ/PWnFK2OLxJ9bxx@I076CleiLX84gXKhz4MDmIxDRBy207dOar1Aq33D4d9n2FL1@qYmh98fCl5cg/K4KYlgcxs0oQ41/QUjN2vKGcex/igZbtChZyS2GPtLcutkfrxra3rmwvSzjDsPHvaeE1muWvK5rN3621hGNUbRD@x8qGWNbKmp5EurYnprG/oGW@vRp@/FUN/7XVcNfRgq8VuEXTBFP/de7/CnPPieqXp73T3viz7fu676KQsaLSfqsx0aHpD759Orr5W2908@zJj7/HeTw47v66ob95/Ht8chrLIz3Qp8f209t4EL/k10528bZ7dnZGj1rLq39QLYN/ujr5re1L@m/wja33ZBsPOmco/u94cEIP/eNj6sno5u/PRjenPf4XvfiS4Ee4u@LAx4dqTZG9UhVCZq/scob7OvNVfh9oh9fMAtYcLzpIWfNTpR10mINnbo5Pe4pViIEky95bzkC4mOfuTJXiR@T5ypGtUE5c2Cx7GqsnhWgFuCaa9AdNQNsr9PKZ/WxSP0YJvtNm8uDohLeuJ5rsz3XApfcDzJRQbjIvGmiYExnz30Hv28il/3seaXbAKIz4171N1YqnqhX/Cw)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
169 [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/),
171 [Agena](https://github.com/stasoid/Agena-2.9.2),
173 [Brat](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brat),
177 [1l_a](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/1l/impl/1l_a_mmi.c),
181 [Ropy](https://github.com/tormaroe/ropy/blob/master/ruby/ropy.rb),
183 [Intel 8080](http://www.z80.info/z80emu.htm#EMU_CPU_W32)</sup>

### Explanation

Wumpus is a 2D langauge on a triangular grid. Each triangle alternates between pointing upwards and downwards as shown in this image from the languages github.

[image]

Each row of the grid corresponds to a line of the source code. Like Alice, Wumpus has the ability to travel diagonally though the code. Because of the layout of the grid when travelling diagonally we visit 2 cells on each row.

In our program the IP starts travelling rightward and as is common in 2D languages there is a stringmode that allows us to pass over the string in the first line. The behavior is interesting when the IP hits the `/` reflector. This causes the IP to start travelling north-west. The IP then bounces off the top of the playfield to start travelling south-west. The IP continues in this direction until line 5.

The start of line 5 now looks like

```
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The Wumpus code is `\#184O@`. The `\` reflects us from south-westward to eastward. `#184` pushes 184. `O` prints to console. `@` ends the program.

#### Minor changes

Because there is a `1` in the Wumpus code I removed a `1` from just before the Alice on line 3 to avoid breaking Whirl. To keep Cubix aligned I added another `x` to line 3.

Answer (score 9):

## 194. [TemplAt](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache/blob/master/TemplAt.md), 9480 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJzKzMpESWSh96xotet8cP9nh2MPas3T3jXew8GNjBYh/W8AALrF@NgX/DN0@LwQL9D3rPORGZTF6kqvq62@sFTInMuJw4EXHixIkTJy7ZVJzeb34Txg87MvVRVzdd5qqOy9q2dqPaKbYxYs8Uzclnc6EQQtXs7qCvGq6zFgozmTHNaGlt8DPXvFYN7ZNqQ3iWMcs2u7bSZ25PcZnqtBRLdZg5cK2By8zO/GQ5xrb75pWWxJR9zegCmKvalq26FL/C2JmhK/1mW5mKyU9laNkQ77AtVf/c/@yyltnvK0bbAcgCY69M21ERvqU6jonJVxkbbqutKaRFAFVszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqFi6OmRK03FtpeVqpoE0ybCTg7OTo6kUsszenO7sTIdm2cukabCdQet6OirHzmxH0ZVp/CusNnDNPXc6PM9qXdVQWDZVSmWnIwtsw1ZmkqwyW1XaHU1XU9AgLMl6qm6pNsMQ1jFttgdF0ouZYqZRG6dMtTBtcRw5jbbE9FzOnapPNgOEN@2eakAJM9ORsh85FZH1I9oaZaDYIxZ1eqYNfGSzgaO22a1pt4G5DH0US0B6NvzEmoqjFlYQQc5HcG2YtwYwkWtC0zZHrsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZvWaDq0xF5p@/PYOZfhHWHTbENrTMXJ7EiBIMpmkvC57GQvaEHrQmdmVw4UrK0yx9AsS3V5JPCKalM0pGa6ZlzzDn5km@1BCzuf21Mhb@ywyA9OqAWpqswSYiKFDhYmDuJgUIITs68Gy@swQ4UGciy1pXW0FmcsdeiqhgNFdlJMg0rcarrO2qoOCcbYWwnmmNi846CmrvRSrVQIGRNzYf1rnWmsZVmMR0EtoEg7mSJTkXrsE8TrPYcNrT5ztD5Euy2z01FV9km1epA81DZDDD4ta6pavm9JBRhD9UijWiAQkDQmUhro5FHo1laAtLYjaOBqfSCs5kYcpiqOhgIVkjiq0SaqWr6oNZkywfLsRoMOD1Uf2ITbUW3qcoQXuqetAkrFb@bora25LvUaVmNHqmKzU1tVY5NidyJLyMzEHFysSIoadX09sn24E4HG5SlSigWNaedOX78IKSxVYUuNMnwrklQObR9ssbulS3RzKQsMYNlRJcYqPzAnfXmpwncoN9Nd@z4EWENAFZ2lTctNK0kLCph0oYBpBZ3oSt5kU5YeyJitT7VFgOU4VBtaA4QPe5OgmrUGto0jyZioyjVUWjeNLtATKmsPDKSHwQoZaIKWCQNBgqk3QDWQvNRGIBeQwqc9DRrNwSYJdCw@HhJBYUQENhYU9fJ1TH1AcJDScZGXgSqQFDHuddgb1lE0HZNAPKLipbZVZ6C7mGZgtLHlYbxT2ynmFYM6rA18fAPZKYCUAoD1@4F@SYUCYGgIk6qKUT/@0z9vd7uAp9ZqgWwT7PqGtc0WjdwKFRaGQ4YMCwJVp2IBXAJz58khgxtF19okIBRjJLKgQlCut@ZAbzMTMrRvNeilPeUGejZ0rparcibng32C9ZVrLk00zrlQ8b7ShIalDChvqnaSPduEVmqpoTDxTLI/cDtFlrS2WcRJfx99uhZ9unipQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9K60Nbq5ankwSwBzS2iwe6qRlsxKQQihzrFTboP0jwFg8ObpHAF4kyngSTH6FQgGAkzHXbDA8Kk7CBfmsggIIdSjq6qVjSTkmMoJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICq9p9XgkHIkHq04YoKYTFcXOeqqZKLZ0q4eDFhDFcCwYCWzk3RaM1CgZHc0FjTPBmsTXNIqAZCGZeKtGbBWHdJ@PqEvyLofpkygoBYZxF5rsyWo70JFBCEBfdp0Zaaybt5AhlQmHGRAdBmaqdKFpIDGvSI1XhOdEIZNV4ooGYGuqrJhsatAJsLuBTBc8H6gbgOeyHAaw8U4SkD19ZQRYWnxYHXcYpnWgL/VBPIA21FJR5oDwUfmAgpkMqP85oGOjtp1JZvP5yT4208VcO11Lvgch/Sn9aE/Cygc7Ewoa1lFvma4Y3YHSVbkmxpRWS7VcIaigJo4Lomh6vKHApBg8U04vtPRsOm8aRDzVYpwHCnneemIoVFC6CEU/CeqMyhQxVQHN0QaxpI@mcweAm6nMpQ8IMlGAD9IDRfA0AGAydai2Bi5INWDg257W6gHPYukMLhf5IDSdPQQFcwfJnuz4WWNh5OqTbCiV9oOwGA@iSGKLzuKBwRVRVScCqPGDAY9jVpz@HMSmX0QYCAKhqbSSAt77As6@aZhzkAIhfbQIMhnD2wE0sRNUKGHg8tQu6qy@luk3EbQZTgTayH8917WcNRgnNLc3aKaAU9Kn9mjPPTSQWdKuPdJck7ubutkEsexA/0x7OaRbg6Y2nKoQhflteOWEbkAB6zisAiP3xwFwXTTScUBgUvgmAgeiJBLchIL/SgBIQCkgVLTjkCjeAaFyMjJaUSlFXSkFnU5KMAk7rgTTHQlT@XTZNPsohdg5KQao6cG0TzNwriBkPol8Ze5Q58t@0usikdSVqRnRu8ji4mJkLVIFyb64@BRc6@h6iq44uJ6SK0kuhEuhi1IkyIWxF5QCw@qR@wsP8zBWx2Yb4qj0SbOiysXaWq6eUC5k8cziMwaiDiQbQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYVL2Fiqaancnab6J0PmnZmiWI8EK5UbhfUCFHZND6Fk4jbbWMg@zjNOlXbBgFQWlt9aJ25PIic1m/vLtsxy/vIwlMHSsrlSZUCvKL9lNd2xzAcBm7WFlLyvVY7CIHg2SzEslElqPRYlKHjJRY7LtiLK5wakcjKkjt6OVlBIgq6HPR6tmEb5jIxmI@qaAcODCDThiNpO6KkH8zVo/FI5A2FknAFKMSiQBlWkgEhyqNnDlBoMPjl5wwm/F4iNjQtK/xOyP2ISwFEyyefAf4d/NkctrbvwbpylqOjqpI0ubaCHjTyzywTQ9f41pje6SxGjDcQg1gtG37MyOcjRsD0p9JuTWDGdF0ECEoDMcelKvaBAwi7mhDmCBAvx95ihCO36gLbcKE09TV1DmpJhKDjoPTXjU1Vxs64sNKquWMeQD0HnBautKCjj2J7lJil4AQ@Dydnh8TK88gnlaVaFbzpTrCwNJSDKRfWyOtfaA5PSQvaFY4lbA7QFVU2UE3UIlqe6wFY34XKK0ONZfr8MBHJ5hkV3GiMdQaa1zrQmUPNQYslGcDoOHcbMF8RwXNAWP55JFtGzeabRpI5NQ2oAaGL2MbTCGfR15go1ptL7v1MH3nIQeKzQTLAdoGsU4Tt@W0WNowdbNrsmUAQNZMpThj7xloKgGdz4XpJXO0T0SgWtc0RlM8qOJw76COKBdyvvatIGSa4FNXIGvY/EqPAR6o88ne@20YIeR8JgPl93wZ@viVDGCZriMGttgYQJhsdeQbbMn3qtUbTRiUkD/4LBL4yVR5x@TzegUGVCiV6OGfKGmwk/MQ6OdeVNtzzav7NmlIaMoIzjImag/KIPRTUR3ebaCG4algDPVIMYF0psHH7bsDsvO0N1BDaqtnMukSNIxslaXb6k0aBY4Egq4HqnISslJtUsb8ZMKEHHLNAWh1bVXX@pq7R@Yu3UDVZTwse7FotRsjONJUNyTmG2Pxiiapsaw1uhx@e4gDkhNS6ckODre2G0e1092KlB44dlrXmsDBbbXRB8VTVx2JTX/C7FgFZCL9p2v92DTdCm@ua5198RPGNF7y/a3G/t7Gce34HS8EoXG0/kBXsChrS1MAmPyEor1eFbADdmyz72vkjmiIpRySXp2w@eP0VMSuYOxAWPwD4QUM76MVP9UKdVstljS51w8UgKsIiJZ9GsO68ThCkqXfDxSQRUKJ1v6U3fQCSxjo2/knLOBjdPPiH04kMN/JmXtE7hgDxwrU7E6WKfzG7XRw1PaDsxR8nURW18fBOQrm6wSTFnpBlpmoucA@vhXCx9cX5uKbiZoL7OPLc3y4LjEf3VTMPFAfWYGQ4TrGXFxTEXMAfUyrhCm49jGOK1LcQwsfIq@50Q8m8nGXCDcujoxR0VKJCPIAs5w7@nzhwmmgjXTMI1l5Ihaj@HIHS7ZhcrKOIMgvn3EhBIJAi3OsdsodumMUuSCKJOgcfBnEj@eMIOsNpQG9clxaLyQQxZI6CDC5ME6c9xObU0lNbRzsg/N2zeoNEAGDQJf2QoJRfiLehN56S7BTZHkL2qY1CvTluywnfl8T4iTQu3Kc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vzWUijndLvs7SuOLGuoZYZsF24YLwFIbefRMUpn3NodXPoGQM@Yr9ZUjyZicTarg0jsmOrYQseTPfvCkFEZHMBrF6beKkeOxqZFJyHrH4KPrX@mzKDuiW9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvSbHfqZA7AmLGcwLOJSEFLlBVr/0bhngqav3hIY2QAIGVBLM5T0MT3QGjCvPJN2jYnCNNXOAJTgNEzS0P0FsGSpSJCdZlN7CBTogkX3nnPA7EFzHtmgt/ZmTF9sgvDuwHZ1tS2e//FnbWiA2ebpKSNS/H1HA@hGvNF5sLVEUvTQz/yWJZirga4pRAZyfQllS8HVBkX3HfNRowbDksmeYvdRvxaNC8yJP9C7HuEzXnJb1Qdt1XvOz4RIPGlg46kNrU81gidOEGk6/EDyKfMgT09TLN1U2oSFT4Q0ddzavF3UIZ8SBDRtkEVfUU7PisfGy2Zub@AO@C@ulH2pXTULv/OpsjbJZJm80pTVtOkoTU19hA9s5XrQNpPWdZcqjUUrPMTtvBOh0SnZ0ZVr7mygcz4BeBVtrdtVbe/5ENhtD3R7mpSkb@nxCKt4mhUjXVl5DKet89@HQLy9Kr7jYTppOv18C0MSi7Sg1yBpcTk8GSCTNkVYXWmOcHLW@3bOwgxJZQXBU2nF45kcjrH@2sd44d2yHk6PAzOlL5Xmp@YL8Zwk86Ysab4An@SGKaqzWJL/Qq@HkUvrK3oy2w44HxTintFz7JoDSjP1ZEtXHGAmVzSHegPNRz@PMTgORi1kq7HrEfYeF8dbAntoNWWcxgJNRNcci/c44XlImk7bocdocEcE/YyTom@Wvm1Shp1e0nfNFwhmy8UVjQf47SsEHF9MwOWaAAOlzIdo1zJv8fugitEzb1T@O3/Q@zS3VF8hqpI6cYbWmpO83foSu@KaOP3Mp@L13FK5LX1uuLDcT04HvpahHU03HZiX4@9jhAAN23H473xWDtJMU4wkGZiD7vnJRKEslhIGtQdaUtG7pl4odtMK/DzY3AO7g@JfPL9W7PliS5a/LLY87cg0ZPF8UN5fp@3rL3ECWaFtXK0KOB8ZbOfJLrHK8XAFYQ6BS9DzK7eTKVLKVJobSR5qALvVu1VG3vMnDCkPUdcbUqwR6dag/GGCUhEcrs317Z@S28rjubW/TiDNoF39UiUCjXutqyCe6XemSVk2I39jCjmT@Xrx1NEH6kCdq@UdNq9U3ITIzbm4c0HRdb4Merp3@I2FyohqLAlzYhqIh8ZEH@qTmDl@Valx8EbfowJG0TXo5F9UcebKOwsUcgsn20fgOELHbMKuMbAmGjdAu@OBcfw45XqW17PN9kQhMeZbJVLxy4rUhM7uqPR9SL/f7pswPzb7oDAYX9H@AilZPvjvBGIKGasZEwaSudn7S9qg0ILiAS2qXTtJtI1/ndDJPjSpJ@BSCaZthuqO8PchSs8Tok3T1L@lZUCWtjXabKwncXvpl1poRskRuxvY2HzhoCmk2XnIcMHHGTHDBOrhbNp9ZP4cNEc9MiWcMa0/MloFDO1fmmTCSE2WIcduee6HGPIYO7WcKqZWH2VHroOaTVVX@GNYWHkMXymVexSfr3UI5ZYWZnAxhy/fjNe/wlOixxoBsbQ2TFB6al8l7yOavdK@Gjje40GgoYnfOdGpNC1GPJDO0qCvG/g7sVQU0IZc04AplavYXRXnJDquYYrQh@Srt8Yxl7h7faWr8rMIj4mOsWkCt73xmdzYOd9IscZ3orQgGV@of5wVoONcqyPHe85F@GrUgvYc9B/FNq@Pt9AC@sVOnUrPXdr5grpn9Mye0VN7NnUO3/dQ9wCOdPkpkscqAeXvKc417vMjeTSey/WcIHV1U9e/hrooD7l0NM35xtlt3KPfhqTfhHekNCFCPL5ox4Mhm4hEY/dDfaenDmBkckzXtNQk@R4C1dHiw3/n25v3DiMOO9dUu803KaD5T3G1pq6yWw2KcOUEV8bnW5OauqngVtJHlHegjPf8GvtUy7S/aPzoKqZrWfRoWPrAoR@y8yY78w2Ya2yHSvo1zKC5fH8IZ1m1azZbPe1LRWqqimto12nPkMO9j85LhTCmmmssuYXBKV0DWtmjFDJBJRh/go@9h8a/wDLO3NpvDmx79GXBMLnq79tb@SoBOh7KXyzQzommIR83QHkbfR5ZqhDruQ9yEynQqCwn1QxoJfKD9p@JvV5CetHC4gNKz1S9qTCBtbRvsV@KDQFkydMCmxogfJ7x4iFBuCvkG8wKo7uDrhP7MuP22qBT4c9chLUuHqviq0mObt4GrM3Q9RVDPOaOyv7K42MLI/lHV0bmkTmVFmugSXXwoL1L1yyH/7JkJzu3eLOL@rNQo/mzX9FkbbXDf7@k6fVNGzfAg0qRbNmq00IzOEpjLiW5CDLMLkjlpM7GwB7s3OLP7iGYp6tMjnjJtwdqV8ENcfsa7o3TndlBEDBPbyf4GsSvB4qjvR6YrjoX5/S2gq9B@Urpaq3diRbwEHrUFbun@GOiU2DQbEPc9jSH9iF7jvkdibMYrdDPRk5b2v3zcI8bRgJ6ktgOypJ7zNs26jvQ1o/xyty8JrVQsTj/oODTXDKgiufces7fgvGYVeF20LcGjnjMz72PpwqCduT@NYU7txpIxeRHEMKsp@jufFtzwJgK@pUYGcfOh7Tu95pudtn7YoaBOgYCD5XwBxhrA8bpI8WFHmA487RAmh1lU3k8YPulsW96eROtF0mu9jgfgTXUHEtqhuY@bqlxXQVmSt4Tq8iVMTxHk97H39Szb8WQPJ1KwbdRHNM5Pv/Eh5MQGxUhTLPFcTMn5Z3pDNOmTjr/4Z0HYGE8lTLA8co17RQjuGhUicdjsRBPhBb/rgFgHhSdqsMTN/zAnsN0zXEJVuuwiwu2dDdcy6zJ96zCpDWJ1escK37o/Mf20KIjccc8@cWSUq8sRZLJyFLk0lhjmYgPrurA6XPBlQnYjkYPXt4xCZih8K276PZqXOYnipwendYDLa8N2uKZQUYc1Dz5uRh@6OoUtxr8h79qi0OMMKV0QM2CkQYIgmd4zb7aM2@f8nxF7jXLUvAQJOIAwaTzIznJzRqDHgNqJT@7aN6ys53TojgRJQ4Mg@eIqx1@KXjjomED9zO7vPF4afy9qSJjP5VXqZapD/oGKPJtt@ek2IlGW5UH9njPIbgQzHBtnM20E2yPtVVc0KUd6DSB103zmo6SYEn@w1/xc2C0D13sD/ayp/OfgRxxu7lMh69aLXMApfaQfFJtU4BEkcggpgZoGoPeqPLwGO7OpgNqwJFJ73gWZcPPaG3WTlhym0XwLDSe@ihrnehS7fj5m4tMvfID66fV//izdOxOEE76LlkqOFKCeSDle2SsYHQeosexESYtDSWeob9JXxOb9G95ewCJFM5kuE/f4zHTtESvoSO2dKLU50Zx1UMU3dTO3jmtPp3OJYZVb@mcFm2ONVB847FXw4EOBt4Yoea9rrIUHXALTvLEZXnIEM@6KeDi53lp2zqeOcIkS0P2mfWQyZIt3EoNPk5IHY@59Ssb3g6fXHAfVnpLbQ5o88FNNpXNVag6S43KepVctto28bjpxfeXw2wmeTlc3a6nHY@ol5fD7zLZt0B1EyaXS0/S2PO2D7bullLVzOfPjjJiknQfKfN9YyAmlu6O9o62T05rp2cn0Ar3nvjZMe2@MpY1yEW0Obpn6nSQF@hia6rzDfLH9wF4NMqWFLaOV1TEYqHgvl8CFbSWktISdwZE00TqLySfl95RA/GzAEKmdTTmcdQejFvYhsBsSDWs/MDC48hMpBVHKonLNJTx2IF8wuDuvDmylEglsQoQKwnE@kpSsYcr@5SHfQ3FvojlcbI9nQuCFPPzu/DjeRXnkuD@d1JvCwbK377eHMvj9SaYR@oNoH6ol2antrd/drw9mQx4jJ4kdSulvNjwzoUz9jRu/PHOkNLZIJEQrV8ViUmUgHvFYEb3jzRV91aFagnh2OrzxMShVH4pNGZMoEwFL3GplzktolEqAeogZazW1H78jjYMFNEbowPo7ngVfSGwI/movYKnJIE5TBdqpPDjVQOxCnJ5Xe@IhLiQ1xEnqP4kvB6HVcMxGhRpSvXAUOWPOg6D/8Co5LmydTZkYjiT6yzJsvDVVZhE9nzYWJmPUWyJE0Ja4mWX/PLiZQ5QpvaVQpNO2hsmjhzAKK0rFp4cF9AHMNFbYx8HJp1v8oSJr1/c4pRG4feWUNO2FKwNnZsyXDwF7o1bhG9v56SC2hlXzUi@B3luYOBABUCBW0S2hzBbAWbrkKzn9xFwkpvi6Ls3VJJV0hFHXX0twWE3mkNWS2yEDuo4OkhKrI2oOF7hQyfbWE13QCdpw/DNL7wh5SRF@5f5JuakwaQw8GTKVxkTTAohrFOZPQoNQ@ltC4bVDzzxEsERZieAM7K@mEwC5bqa4V05s4bGVTKHrDHXHuAWgGpkJolXhDVyJXtuXw8AzrkU4lJN//hP/5xfBHHpgvsXwj3MbIDvj4SvA@5/4sXIMvj@me/Lgu@Pue/7NDbZ7Ol3kb2wfj642Rv48pk0UyeUCd69O1QXv7Wxpd/sHTGHLMDYln1lGGgmlDDIc5oB9NL6wBQ31MYIznMYN@EYT/TiDbAI8BXwB6o3qNFQfqpdj@IZ6LV0GguO09IU7RlWh9z8S0eiPw7wKhBQwtKFfGFFTkMhkzceQjqX2MVNqhxhLLYGMjF0o1mVD80WHj1gktNSdLVSKHPeSC8p3@ekD35BlwA2xCcKFwzS4GkFPwXEVUWy6JISl2OYFAeyiBxBmdY2OauBNhglB4DEMNjwDnaBumkKUgEfG@rQJY1p5E2AmnjlE5qpVH4hjIcoCYg4brywYro7jred4i79QAdNBZtBOkewEwRbk@Yx68X37NK9NOri4hIGjPerOaxrgPsfz7nNhHMWntScvUYjOn0JBtaGPTsxTNyevAOlZdFsOptLy4VYgEMlgQrKi139M6CEzg3CoqVqV6bl1Da3914cHp3MXAdBkJFpsAiLVNfjl8lU4qLuOyJ@uSeJurGTPnm1seORMliq8eI9QoxX8KeLOS@36ZI@kPs53@87mzdFzGQkZ74WMS2XJXdog8ss9nFsOgC4yfcZzuQajd3dX9TXq5dGeCb7z/OuyAmnlpG5wHXp0AU5keliYhH3vF3Mp3j1npPyTrNkpfEFUP4ZHO4fBz98oYN/kd/4Vgdvv3SIzlv6xy1DqQd2UkPdU2meFV1pwAvmlRdkjVdUGYs6zrAVmtmAESwNE3WZvXNQHCjyiXTIbUjejXEOh3RIOHMrE12t4tPMhzv1MGLXH9@zIC4Y6EHpdK0ZuhVnYb3jWP452JRj6ZobjYUMATF9MGsW0nn0ugIfTKlcDJl/wshBnXGYIuNclG4Duq2H@G0PzLuUIU73OhwNgG5HpsXGVrQt1XMdg07FtgaQRQsnZC8GfYDr0ONYxdFCBS0rCYmBnhGvKBd4k4GgRKrfzkeHsVRPHba1Low40VgCRNN3sjy@EULBKw1Ar2rOqwGapayeAnXApsmt44UKw9h6ibzjCnIDKLudH2zUQ4AMkzZja9xyETkzvMt7sOHXWCThU6YZS0RSjM@kxL08tIhMhqgU2@zhljsyfXQ6GqlswXPWfDDvaHY/hbWCYYaz0HPccBvkmm@6nCNAGeVCSWlGWx1G8Rz0Wh3pBOGR2/ObSEyaYXG6IUTcB9GevirEk4WKK4TS@JqNKXlXKvlyblI0lEqpnhPCs2owKYEcT1x7H5ygIkQ7fcVi0QHdteKwFCNv9DJqJBzXjrFkFYfrW2aweJxsGvCgCJizIGiHXBodao/i1WTRdAUaCUMdo42PT5rFLuRUqg5uyiTGltCeuQnaFFoCYyGYo0KSNUIL@gX8rWGJ@EWSKXGh5BJlG6LrDgBqbjTJqW6P5AvQgmrNqk/GZ8sDAoZTtVRaE60xKe1LDPhifY5ABLRzpLg3RwD6itNGQDWU0QC1aattDeTls5eqYahAIOCZPt6bqQyAyexYwrvSNTG@co1yCPMi7orjS1DQyavYtiN3ugnq2lK6TKax8j2oNR8uUa/pCM1mlP5v06l0@S66pFdGadA1Y9XoUq8ix3PL8fiSsRxdMlDbevIELWr3S6DMNVIwQR0CUHJJj5WBn0H5qywZ5SVlPbrUrmSXKQV4YYp8Bwl@cNKpuyXlPr30BJSlBITYXOhElxy6JSWTSsn3UD7sIUvpBPDMHV73QRe1YvZLWjyOZUgtNbAAP6QvT@I0bF6epMl4VxZzgXS3L7rblCrmt8TMBbOcgCJ4zR@w8jhgiV1oDQ94fBFbbl7cA@ofz/gl7tVltMVAdYKTL2ky5usFi5DTKHOFkInya2qAgMMoEBG9CSUWA2Hym9@E5QJj0tNCLmrGn@Yz5XgkL8M0HebX4Wegh6eXJVu6u9xK3jA1GbnoKPnUx/rR9dHR29hllJVYJLx5KMkr0veslGVf91ll2Qc@7Lf5hMPL6VA4vSw/WU2nP3z4ADMO@FxUU1UQH/wTu0hG6hfRVcaqq6vLiUJxOfEs0ggULBbNZmMnLM0uNU2znHYbvmaPblWOhvnn6VPKC6b/8M94mMhfODwPgojQ8LfCKfkwu1xVlOX4SvaZUYailfCTYzI48bcIX5nl82wbP3/7v//tn/3tn9Dfn9H33yvsmn2Cz3WH4T@5P7UDbgXdzc4nvEUGphYVkgtWJJLPRU6@j7D/bJ9FJlefrv6nPzn8GHbD1Wz63IanG/4YLhTD3AkO8OU83024Gl5HsMJ9eJSuVCrgXP1P/yukr74APBgzWoefat7DVRiFq8kKJfkcrhbAIWezkO///bOfhcLVYfhTWJbl8Ij@GuGMjJ/iE/kJY@BIS6tFyTSfeeUdBj5eWFqWs5fj9gw0NzatH9yDfKBdmRmeBCW3z1VMcAM5vgUO7w0uLD77sMWYCkMtftbWns0QfH/Kf5xKwiclusEQPcmhV4VwsZJo8Ox9Xg0HHFMV9n@ZqLvv/0a4UNi7/DJ5oXTqE1S/DMvFlcNnw6/@sHGhPSKGx7TzM2fTYR7VfQ/zOj37FrhQ@IdK5djFv1dN/Ds6wT/zI/59u5hjT@GzCH/0Dx/fi7@LFCKCCWT2s/hbdNdQ@CJ8Ua@/7tGfjX@7Bv41P@Lf/if8e@3i32kL/45f49/pe/x70cG/l5/wjwmeXV9fD8fjx6AaCp79ms8ZfFOphvB5vIvofqcfFmLhZD2evL@/SH0/jJfL4h/0pbLvww93QYnq98nk@vfVePyCSnZRFUVcT9arUExeWvr5fh0Qx9cv1tdTjWq1mqx/X71Yn0wk0j17Fscu@gwSVusXF6HwHTZDBX@W8afl4G9WktLkxXECBuYSuBg56SECGF15j/5Q@MP6h2j8afxpRs/cZORr@fqVeTj@PzwcQoQ2zFyZdqaX6cltEIYso55lRpnRMNM3D@U2OFX4y/TBqWU6w0w3Y2QMWR4NJ1DR//By5bBw@Gw2Av77h6b76tAEpCYgcIcZF/FnOvDsHh6@ArQdKMIV/GmZTGYIZR1mbuA/o6Oopku16Pl9I3YZumDSBxXG/5QcSWUiqUIkotXzBevj5d19tvBRSkQalxeRejmcdi4v01w/YtmVMl2pdn/faGwfbDUaaeSk9aX4s3jyGXwq1fi6eDwNV8tPL9eS2IycA1ONcHr96WU1l0R3IQ5tlYWw9XT8Gz9jlPCsLl6GYMp3fo7f89ubW@4iB7kuz8/9WPxJYxC5KAg@AJqem37CwUDX/D39tw//y/p/dcaiF/UYY9G7@/UofWL4F4vd3d/di99qLBoVnug6/GEA@DHJ3X0VnQR0B66LaKweu7/nYfAbja1zhFXMY71KiceA0G/DPNfLSBl0vMpSVCyrXV4OM5lYuQkhvoFd@UwrNLEy7V1ZauKqGswH5OUYgeRXyuUV4V4tlstF4ZYLhXJ52YfKgEc4AUh1lFYZGb0cjmEROPdHM2hVoWsrI9G22sH7y59aFkzt5FLm82c/qNFoa3ajgeG5z58voSNFcOdKpZSHkEzx82fog5EYTPsOTLFmWoJJnJzOolMGZ359vbBSrRZWwF0oxmJl6WLpjhci2o2X5Bi7X0rXVUfiZYTpViTM97tE5eJqjELvI0tpqczC6@xpFdjXgQ@7uw8TJdlKPhZtjtQYWylEi/GS@Kssxth6urrMxN/FRS6@sry6/KxeHysJ2OHLd0pFvq/cKWs44b8vt8T9j7irT3nyJFeCKhYz5ctQo7FVO6018CJ9SUKhajGGoSQ7QrhSaNmRCzLP5Ev1Cyx3/TISWSs/421UzLNwpCzgkhGQQqxYouqFYQ6odXA/7xBltfiuycvZ3GI6P/yusJ0BnfnzMn4uLi6K2WJ8GaTUcqlUr9cp9PMipbnoDzt1umKokryQC/l6EpWRq2FnGQorr@bCyyGL9gWtZlgbl1ZtNHctQmBPcVgTV8EdVde9OzdvTVtv32ptFbAf7dc2t08T2XVAmd2pbSayJ2cbYRm9@bGfonPoP96ubR2eQYKj/e3ayfbzvTfbZ0cQ7sC4B8SCT/9IUQdqQ70dDG7R31Dps6k5ytWVYlkNCz7Dzo@/@vmPv/rvfvyLP/7xL37@41/82a9/@Wc/h@9fwfeP@fOP/20pj7@//uU/@59//Nd/AYH/Hr7/Dr7/x69/@S9@xr/k/xv4/p@BsL8R3wAc/wIpAdsf/fqXf/KXv/7lP/mX8P1X4vsvp78//un/xv//L/GHzr/48U//Bn@E5@d//OMf/smPf/gHP/7hL378w38IyP/@r3@F/3/y13//736F///Lv/n7v/4f/v6P/idy/Dl3/D//6t/y37/7g5//3R/@87/7g18@8PvzR39/@RXhv/w9hHx9Ob8Gz9fU61tDfvmTyvPbUGOcCzHYn/3jH//FPwLO/VPu@@/BB/9@1C98jx8Tp4laMj4O/AVjn9OgCGWeffZBAeX/iKEQzD5PYqPQjBf661/@87/E4AnYfxTEkJFnYZcQ2M/tFwD7r/2CBWF/8eOvfvbjX/7DH3/15z/@6o9QoCVXSolaIil/Ya4DgPmvgEPAwtfAAaC8jqvbi2wxlAXH4jqaIEJy/MMHIOkiuECvXg7lc@ALyVVyy@iGhDBDWeZz5DjO/OE7DK2UwIdGgTgMIXEeFYeojTirVCrx0LACcQQKXkwzZNUizmZxKlABvJiIp0k0iqBfsuEGYYGUlfgxayxXhjxhHAOqhIFhgTDoWJKzUrxY2YIMK8MthrgQeTz0AZ4fKtViZVhFdD9QEQBHfAOyBKgKlm5Y/QH8FcIJ8KHh1g9QlGIlHq8WIaRCVaXcEg3KU85T5ajucUb1xnDG0Cb29Blj30lyUeKzMSAlE9D4Gx9DPyWbxFOIv4wvi@rQv@ek7zKmh3YaEn14GI9/isGUXgAA3mQSd0LBN5nE0jyD6CFHFads4RHnGIBycWG88QNolI2H4tS@cfJA/lCGr/usVwMeRIfVWVpaAtd6VcpJh6DUM/t6zXEVGxcKSKNZY1KhJGEwbixRl45I7V/eWoZfGf63F2lzKCfHcmgpgkN5hHl5JOM5c8UMU@m9qlFdlqnkcYILhcfhXNWk1R7QEVdYLBSlS6RjNIVULdBgQq@c7oY5BH0wIUkJuVDiRlMxw3xnrq1VfpBXVkPwJP8A768WNylDM@A7jVLYu5Cg1bvkOvU0cIK6UQhVq2LFismh6sn2KSQ4PWRyNpNioETeraxmV/Ir@WyuUMivZuWVQmmlkC/mQEIVMvlsVi6trJSKpdV7KNAz6OeJteVmfr36D2Y@/80/mPeZH4qfUPUtG6bY0dHr5H2oOkwm01kqckXOr5ZHFSgIBYWqpElxfXl0lwSlE5sndEmbo@5wHw4ULXSXRFZdgA8LLYTYAgTBBzCjvZ6JReS9w7JYTcO3A/AVNUnOAzPEQpfADBxbyAp8QthuT0DYPJG5M18YOzPoPMXzLgeAHlrBYPu4adE12anJN8dtqK3QujiXUQ2FaOXhAmhaD@HN2xf10Hraj52PabPH35e1aZugof50mA3FuOZRWxreuddy/ahdBS/Vcfqa23sA4szq4ykY1f69YdjuN6GAaHjkABvwY@umOQ9glZ0dPVDLV/75OVzCowN0AH6893z3NPA83a5t7oYKbOPwYGvqkRdAeba/vXPqe1d5rJc076N4t72/P@0VD5xlLLL8aiIB4hF@8JmgDz1TS997IHLq4XFTTWUSMgwDjZF6l0zeN1W8W/2E3x4/7OimI0ciXbUP4xz0ZBmYHXfQdk0dJlRLmc0MrjKkP@OEqKFm8yO2BGKxBDNDtp6vFsJSXipWCpksDD10qX3HKIcLMEe8KNUrQ5ZjxYu6FXZWyqVc6BVu@SrJ/OiC5oR2YQbTxwu98SC4G7LVNsxmbg06ldHEl@cMLPZgIDwwCJ221u2BaLw1fQCYWIaaisLg@60fwKEGP@7jAS7Pg8JmYvRZ8NCtbxfyDT7Mt/wIiXGO@4bpzJC3wEzDj7MWOkVBTe9UYnicrYmvIaBzZaAB8HO29NIAFcR2KRTCRTWtwzKhFBnKsqVivljKZYuJYqm4koeJZT4hZxPyanG1BBySkYtyoZgvyYniSim3AkIbYvOl1VAYBJvWSadhTJIliZ6a0cJrP9fx/lQz1auGwtzQAIoAvoUurPgBgyKTcsXLDIOEUgj3zy4PKxK@5zGDb1GUpZCksBYL7@xsZnZ2JGkDPWgV3MxIUhs9@WIms7ohSSrFbMLAkoVEPfRtF1C3lSQNPZu1nR3EcIWebBFxSNI1j@Ee3fOsApiBnlyOlGNJ@uijywByk5eoSKlc7slkNjYlacCLh0ceAa7GfStU2G30YAQm2uExmxAnSc@9RBkgg3TM4URWu159azVJ2uOeWg1RvKDK53mlXqKnRh9IZIMPOF@SuuDo2jDhl6QmOJH/JakFrtZIgbA@uPAgo@EqkjTi9cCaSNKQoJXWtQQ6nwiHfKA8u7tKz22rXf4Z2fzZgqg9iNKGg@2d5vPnzW63aY9q28@PKerFi13lajSwm92mSNhswMfEVBB13R9Nf1SMajQUfX7US4gypqIao4ZKJWwoH6Fk4tPFjPqNFxj1AqLmrSIJhPDpA3ATPxt9eG4oTR7lfSiKnsNmUyojy2LX6USJcZUEPZosdofiMKo8BSV@RVpDeWp2QPUaFGPJ/NNBUSqsSmvL8JSeSjlwDqOZSIYxKXIpSTGQjE@l1by0Fnn6NBl5Ij9l0mpJWpNWV6VY@R7Vi2jsrhMdJoaVDASk0@vYj7HnwRO0GaGKnKpDN7Wr4g6OVjJ5PvFZXz8HODx0igfwDgZ9tsFuSXTgdnxvR3KjsgFyIlM28FC3it6lYXgYqrYVV4FJycbdYG1NwN6Xu5ULRPAZf9aT0nn1XKqzYL751QyU6sxoZVfX1y8@10Ejq8jlURhGkWyxPAzTiYvVlXIUJgCxiqN@5HrZZx0taYuNSoZraEvOoH@RWSzIibtkI3mvK467JK9m1y4GSxdJub64mPncXZfeV6U6Zo@KG/0FzX0g0MoQ5pGMi8BwR/sA8WwtyV9OIRcLsRRuDG@YnQZdQM8@BCTdOKFVhjFWV0HRkEvZsgAJWRXR6BKL4ptl@A6VaCSymo1EYpEyQC1CsGhN4havuSWQtNDcpSwojWVbdQegfGTK9145/SJwhbUgh8L3oTbeO7pSCoXvQvd39@tVb2x/yUYjJZ70vE8Y68Zh7pKm5QhcyFgkVzJVfcZqlVr3uFYWoLVNmmEAR13yg0/J9OK3LnrE16vf8@dlFZcBIZ8QJw8tDabX49V0tVq9DEmSFJY8m3W0mId5CU7efwjTtXFs864zMOjo@NorJJiyxrWTi3rshwNNvyvmklXSe6PQH@7D8fU0LqqlqmmiVuuQVptDYcMUTrR6utA9oqCa5yWcBKnMOil9v/p98ftXZ4dnhzvsWWatuFbkpKDl/2eJhByRI0DaZzDqacfbobD12czLPxgvyuE1K5JbieQm1KrLijj3G0VOiF6gjf8iV69fwASnHgNfpZJ9KueL8ZU1eTUWruL5w@xquEoO6HbJXLge5ghWVlkMPGRfzsrhalqEy6tyLOwkuQ/S5MNOKFx89eEzTE7Fmy@1LLnSaVGqpfv1e/iv3l/A/O2epnH39I8/afi55wDwj@C@hz/GnwBcEGYcX/8huc7/1@ln85CXWSoAxcMfKlVo2O8b3zfCoXApUo2nI/gWZ7FPQcyMUCFaNuhPdZbx7/txwDLocMu@D7zryyxflRlTl9Pp9GXsdRb0mVKpUCyEQ7@Z/aSXYQ63vFBjEX4DC9ej6HXm3gGXyMQrtHDqvbyQ3Do53HwJM1xQpFQDXyXINg8PUhiFb7sbn1Bq6api6yPxursRQqH@dbp5hC/EPts6ojTndDaNQmmGLXJZ2muvibdNJG6YnMqxbCaTT2dW0nKeycW1zOpatsAUEDoOnkUXriVMyqham6Y14lpvdDNGiRdqCINx@xpMWRx1jT0/2qcUdEx9eWFr@9UhOzzYf5fyQnn46e7eCTs53Dk9rx1vQz1ebZ8wqXbC9k4kdr53unt4dspqB@8YRB/XDk73tk8QQTqE8grXOjjBfJWQrTsjJ@2OLNUhvXAi2DFb16o7Ga7YlpLGCwUngw18xYCKN3NPhg8MmPe1gyrnSW0BZoKDFr4EuHWttNt2CA/FaS22gMP1wrJq485RqZdxVll@8PZTxs4vstbKQWSVtTIHRm59lekZ8cf0lX7umC0uLl4aki/tg9XwNd5gEG6nhrBxmfbeby9ECytsGfTc7EpsHHNweLSQ8XwL58enC7Ifd7y1kPU9ezsLOd@zDb4V37dzvrWQ930btZcLhXGyg82FVd@3tb25UPR9wKQLpTHOg60FORPyiHVjau0Feo1SdGdvf5stA1CsPBGLNg90TAUDIaIDw@E3FCDJ2fLybc/Et8DD7Gc0Bd1WvwTtgU9ALaBWcoF0rSfYsmnBT1/tAzAkox3OUXpdlt1tJQRWvFoDRpDQXWgBK7SAFQL4BTwbi3BsscKyMQbRCx2@lhvltwQlmHTm0Am47xy2jrpBFZghQXd10ElISKGKt56FFu4FymiH7EId2t5JoDKUVLKlWAyPTx2c7e/zzCzIwrSjEkEy8khzcJoWYIMqwi9WHUJ54/BmobZAWi0IDQLfzBa6n2jN0HRrIimgngsLLUAwSd0bRU8wVLYSuLCIeNHDt2UDMESDOwMufm4sGm1hXbuq26ICxZCY24c7vIa4NFlhk60cY5gpUYqi@Ybvz5@Z57t0J732pNeIcNwCOS8Wx8dLWkHYGIYteAf2CIIOJ1PKBeSYeBxSQ3UoLlCvBSA6fPlZZq@UVcgoE2FPnlA51sFXilAWmC5OObIkgiACQTAiHyLzi7ZIxY0tpJdxEwB/rTESEccRfr9fc@TfwwCSdbqgU63q90K/ORcM1XHLUwJZRHXa2NbgzmUb4EfxCJycYE3oJgnmRcoFjMR5RYKpCdaB4CmZ2tAM4FzVHstEjxWgM1LrH2zxFuKXjlA4D6Aag9xbowYDYfEEuy8x@sJC01aV67IHBfKQoIBvkWmiSAgO93i64y1Ktsz7C7Ilpv6alHs7ax4f8dTADoLTiKw4a@G8IqpLgdUx0Ax@gQz7bwXQc5bkyOJxAeFzmQDbnoRLJjncvceXX6jE9nQtFr@5FiiWH6zF9ldW47erBQxrYxaBWoCIjwLeOEDTz2RrZuehgLGQUFBtfhoKGEDHvAR9fALBV6SHIXecPvnt6WGQXpvuytBvoQW5VOBJJr2tSW970ovdF0IUBlOC7Ar7zJrokgvgwvPCrAiONpeVkwk7k14yO1SY6qXp@BKY5wA8h6KSgyEDzgpjlCApB@8iV/r4PowKq@009g62TydjEV/KaYiC9/CV0JRHbBJMFAjjnSh6Yn6Joh0kAtc3o0c8jwTRs3Fyerxde5WA8sXY@rgHTOsA8CN6wkQN7r0cINRQWzAetxMselJjyzH2BEuWYMIygJ6vzkI3HRVQPZhje2BlKasMB/H9kz0pjD0yNCcrKcqiMfb58hKG1Mwqk/vW51w/Z6zm2myUW0Vll@PxdRAh5T0Bc8C7Jlc2EBLYU8EbL@ZmdpXJsBU7x1y1Bxr3MGPP4qd63ePYRsOid6rRMmlS5pTpreIoW8QdEDAuTqo2j2uRNDYiH2AodmMIw@GcbFtx0s@RPSnWU7B4Wdrqt5blSxrtZFmSvCzrlOlsGX4jzHswXQpNnVylqzRMy7UUPNwpIg8ttJscYZAdCnF7SuBGpaiJbyFwY2t0EwbKlEYD75NrNKKOqnfw1cQDuwVDPqrLjgDDD8ameCR1JHRMRgryoP40GdHW8DAmXgQIo84UQnpDcoXub4tSjqGQXzLHVS0qVaAYaBPDV3QGM8S3zAf90Kx4SCpQ4tia0Ip3FOwPHrKLiUtwOI6B00vMCQbxPBvqs@mcOJ9t5sThXWfzkniHd@fEXQ3680oAguGBGHH8bk6MYR7OS8DvkBlH1C8CBLwIErhej8bmNz30q8kWD1wCRPQ/tQequNFm7zDAgqBcCg4MtHV4SwWmbWl4t/M0Iv8AMKSMDmOBs8g@W8XGnKQ4LU2bRu9hEojoMB1dX8yGa/iS9@F3crYYSwQQBjDiJXV9RX8IJwsghRLOQRLmb@NmnqXT8VEjC07jHadP4VF6ow3Tu3EC03oEHmPHsNj4HvAC3oLkx/jMPKfLjdGtzTIOhaMtHptfnrgv6iForxJyLEjQ3zb75Ldmnwzkj33yJ2VdYReT5ajHA/41CBjX0evgPykjr9STucW@qcZBrlHV6wfYF@/1CGTDz/NPZuujERLI5ymvKoQeA75SSCCuIKJvkC/UfOK08bzU4/FnucKSsp@GS7xxbyCreqDwIbyJoNHAKzwbDbq7rdFAy1KjIfEcaODFAS846IrOxuNSoKU2TIqNSklFSkjJZO1kc28vqRlSgl@PW5Ec17TVBl7BJCXaMFGqSCSwGgjTU3WrIontVorDKLX0cB61QB5QwS9nQkA8F3qDevBuzi9n1wpWyfyKKplTmY3vC/yK3I4pNzwa/VhONr94y8tok@6Gwsu2bFVDQcMv/hXvt8VLFCbO7qNJXxSB5@uQpc/BGxN4kejRwDDR1nj1AL1FuMLI2id5d4lIM1d/iN6Oph5EMOZUzn3SEb0uhNG9Um1V6FlkHkpJ4zsFRcFSoqYBfvcUNH4Vw3hAm7xfRJQ34dkmHTRjThV1LFhMCyt/IeH1I9AAR6YFv/4VJOD2LyEBN15DgkGeqAM33kGCKTrCIa4jARddSAJPYG9pfP9hXxlq/QEaboKH3IUmNy4WDvlYExr1KXJS@nGKIkRKx4tkowJvLC6tSVB1hy4/mb4ABeHn3YESq4dmhSzd2IvFDKgO85DOvVUllvgdNFJAEUPR7IjSQNqExCSuhFBaea0Ok88A73giBtXnqTCTWz0REdQk4acfj1eBO1QqE9MLpAhMHnhhxgm4lSn4Wi5S7mNrvgoybrEgFFfc5pQbt0s@WPAgBk9Ri4UemUn9/2aeFGyS/0KnSv/fT4pmpj6/56nMI1OYb56t/A6nBf9Vof@vCv1PUOh/Z9r8Ayr5NMrZHj@lrn9RDf929Ytk3giGDbt7g6a37E/Rw35HisDqN@kBXqkv5Md0gS@Pzx6abHBY/4mjdOg36dN24XzHrNVqp33ZPn5e69Z6teN34N/I7MfPr1Y2tm43nm@0a1tb3RfdzQP1dbG2sm@9fFt897zz6aMK2vvu4Yv3n3Sr1Qu9PbZuz9Wj25xadGqDwce93ZG7u3HW3zzJv1u9zWzr@c6G@nFLd7Zenb59efo8fxK//fji6MWnfqbvHHUySqmf231VeLM5OjdC@RvtrL2zrx32T9rbZ9n@/pb2bie@mdk/Kb2WM/vbt@9zm7fxfCa9Z708fH58dtXcfq8f7@2/a29@NJXCx@tbay/dLnU2r47fhA5zr@Xdj4eH3e1s6flu@narY7Uz2V3dzl@9PT7aOHu323upbPd38melt1ejo0Lv9esb9yDeXTkvDF45K3Gj9vp19qXx/OZm@zjUVMxTO6eem69l6/b2yCz1V9WXB7vd/mtbNtKH@Tfxk/7p7db2hv5xdZg7e3f@@nbl5N3g1esX7w8z2slJc1spWM129uTqdCXU6uf24jdn22dF5Xn7/HX/Zm83/24r/aqnHtTaR/r18@7ue/PkaH@vlnMGhry/eaO/e967enW9tbmnm0fXulFbSef10/a7w8PQ2QutuaXuvnVe1K5679L5jeuVd/G29fz06lPv@sXGydlhMTs8GmXMTee4udsZbh0XssV0S/94/KljvpLPXscLN1cvstq72ic3lPs0ypf29Xdq33gRb3XfDz/q6fiZLG@@3/v07t3J7o3drBlnH9/sHF/Zr9rGoXOYOX7x8lVTvy66V9Z74@REbmWeq9ev4hklNDzbdaCN1FMlv3ra339tDbfMj8d7753Cp/jN@XVO3bo@flP7eJxp3hrWW8Pe1/qbmfahUntjutuD4fNW6ebselff/3jovAu92pbz@R2z42x03qyU3qafxzvXz99uyCfDzIFx3Fkp2AdvXp9r2nbv7dmn41Z@541V7LtG9/Wns/52fHt/2PukFjNN/eTdtRE6y58cH2VvjZda393ZPX5VcA8z@2@O2rsjufZalW@N1c1RfmtoF3LnW2/td9e7hpV@p30cHGXUm3j7neWuvNaandYbrdV/GTp50Ts7OHpzu5cv2M/7hrZxVMwc7O9uHnTbKy9He68G2/vNq/bzvbfqW@u0cJ3d3jgvbL09ybmn1y/dUuumnzsqxk/1vts9i4deDHqD1aNz@@Ob4fuVWr@p5o71d@ZoVe5vvrCywze17cNP3esjyzyQd7Kj9Nm@ea1nPp3eftp1CrVRvDg8c/umeyoP8/LrUO72k@W@sF68PjnceHH4/oWyomnnytXJm3Ymd1ZMaz07t1coPJe3dzr9j/2SKn/aepVTcv1e3Nm/Trc322dvzq/1q/7L/lUrVCw5rY299wPF3G5m5cy7jc52Xt3f2D@V1bPuy5OVrYPM0dv20dnH4Wl78@3g7M2hltm@elHa7668PX5Tern6/tQ5Vc7Nty/tg9CwmDMduVDK3@ZOSsXDnn2SO78que9fXhU29POm/GIv21d3NPttcVS8tj71bru3J2qm2X2@9VE57myDJD07yij5wfXB8CSUe3Pav1m1NuLvrlsv3xqyXjzXVtOnH69K173ey9ut1sp57dNHJf/8Si2d7KSb@k7@efx48/XRVXfr/FNxpZ3Z2H@jvB1u99x3ode72tZV6fz6cDiSX@@cjPq1jKHnb07O8zen5sbJ@e5JsfeqaXeau1c9kA390dnV7eBmV13tDW@LL3tXb5TM/tvipuGsHGVCL9S9fvv49OXbWryTVUvuzeG7A@u8eD7Mvyqa5yXzsKi9rHWeD18fdrYzq5Z2fjo82@6lNza1fhFkypF@Zm8evt59f/7CyoSyRmHj06aZX/0Yvxm@K5ynj@L7g3et02z/3LZ332r2ztubo7cvT2p78b3m6PnRtXL4bjt/crC56byI72gFdbSbu3Vqmzm9Y4ac/sbwYGhbpdz76/0ujARmu9R@fpo7N5xarXO7VzzZrtWeO829F8pw@LyzCmMEfrbP35iV0G/4/WYhfrUZfyj88oRQ3@k2zSHIS358K0QHbEJ0wCbEj9TQdmi@0/g36eXQafCkDL1Ukht4Bk1Q1ljbROUhxfb8@0LxdQEJ1jchuYaulmnRE9G6ttYcuOhzTB1@yV6FB8ToFVjq0NJNDd/EgrfC45zUVvkpNFBfUqFDg/VHON901T4/v6Phy1TE9Z50kTx/Zw1dLxhaaLWY96KwFF1e6b827AMoEJbRTdJtpV2WTLY6utJ1wKG3yfUhdOLfpo056JqCxg/MQt5vKHImL7amorpKhTvFd8AcPGe6ya@p92YcCigTI7o4Ao1UdHmEiu8ddbQbVR/RewfUdirEd3x@1S7IYBhu454MoysWp/aGgrqh2lMbQC2e0FtpTS8/w4s9ni2nxRIrKkMNxW5qLr66ssFfV9DgOXp73qzJvYd0aFMs0HLFCDUbupyUO/vKEH1TqZBitJ0cDxm4IntUDVFF9XYbLi9bhJL2XTHuCWBeth7GrfW7vyvUE7jbmjqB1wRaDYBWtCA9s2b/nUObHH2gcogv1m@/3TttiJdT8C2GnFKP77gMULns@awyr0Gg/KLks9sycYcBFB/NjvxuX6jqjcl5WaJ9j7g9ElobZ9jj3Zb0amYsOmKzaDfKxUqd7yDM0NY9j@B@miecE54ESvVkTNAFsaHC54GvTMc3aHKQ2foi4o6tqgRAuzm9YyBTm/1@x7z3QMs0dcW4RleZb5WF@YLdCjQWXbsfqAeasvy6iP2TNEfAekNSfxvsuKCS7TcLAYgNsV4znxnYnWm/PabhLexnjfYxzMOfdem62YqOo5e9LTe8bjEvJw4/ldUhWhI7uLPWtEc8IzTPRMtlAMF9OiQTVMPbrRqodWVMDURHm3oCpQC@LXtBeEJcHZczwR4vLc9qkdiBdgDNLyrfDIRQF36x6jyrh2Uh0DsWrMxE0jFxvC1E4EwvM9e0gAgdwXEwjBGP8N2pM1ThO718LmKcTheZOvyzp0HPGt@4ix1KRbMnipAYdmOcoU8Vzi80glb9roNZjVmPGgp3cGMTasSLTIMZPoYzLR6faKcA8gsN6SazOFE7OicWxJBfI0F6QXuCoT1x0Bp8Ky7r8B1cnNahKRKtQ0afP/sdBrw@Nx55B3yBJfwX5SKDc87kfVkQtOz5vU7ouylmTBRfqt7P7qVH7u7CBNy8tbShqkdBYDbwpRsWgyCxZcmyuIMg/O1LEIyNTWUX8mpxMQqpLgguXayzJywqr69HV5NRCvquGIv5nVEkzwaSBxKDkK5WWTS7HM15iVcwMaDMTSJYmY8gyxGsLEdlD0FWIJDzgIGrGITkO1bkXDuJuBhA7OOtT8Lgqzvm5L6cjcv19fUi7vEMBE4lzs4v@nIunoXEHPVCfDKGo@URgfD6ZI0AeS4bGEcCKFbiOUDBs45PRoxznYrwMw3muVKfOzj9zpQX75yGN/hQcnyDoGpfFLG@yKl8U7rFwG25tgjEtzhZ9C6ncRhn6WVkc9ARqEtCbj0VD00l@Lu8xKAF9CtPjYqBwxEEgWKAiODh0RLs6rGxrvntgx0Cd8jAx@ucYHKCFWEaAhIFJEYREoMIIRpo3Uarb/lwMBQXY3zHNx/AKJMDXHHG8wPQTqj2ezmRGOPkwxVuwCfepURjCKdvFBI09vc28PFm@xh3zO4dPIcmXMB6JNj416vmIsfoV3FTMfj7HTRXgyKAbOMTGlFX3lST@WOgl7/A5iEX8NPYeUKqHUIwnlhoh8QXmtvQTIGNk9LjI9UlOtLrhnyAYqwM8wx2qzJFR3KM@GtSi/ytRHTojVITqcDhJxQFRAohzU6PawcnO4fHr4hyR43a/tFuDTHDBLOl2G1G783ADmIYqs4HVZ@eIRx@QULzOilN7yUP9EZiguUvYOPEA8AGxTQodLpEWF/O9DPwPHheApIoPjQoFY22as3BjXtXfTBRGWcOQt6KvNRiKBRlmjcS0oA3OxJ6crSKko5oaaqOEXGBsek9IorB5Unaw7cBs0x6CRv1XNSjusQvNn/rVC5Lr6JFPnIGFq4Oq20pSH6l1VIdulFjTH1AqeodykRIlgChIGR@7cfyg59N8cdegYPexEeDbsbXe8dq7qSyCNojp91P0nEDChLH4ulId55aSWqRyJm/GXdCddQmVcaHMuO5XfHcriA3LnDZ1bRCptUvriYUsXnk0TzyXHHd2NPMuHribyWnlutAp3d6eAcM2UK41KEGw2bC/UK2OZqQdU@8Jnvi9eJxT5yv3D2ulAnCTmpkYsAZj59iwtxuA9miM7YNOrlCs6@Bje3PPYZ6ix4aKflBJ2@KQfDEKQ1Qpz04T3ziGaoHOQMxgTSk0zIXIrs6DSo@vqhAyJJeeWIBXYNOYQqrgGaAtBgfThN1JVXSdMREMRCIYlWMwnbb6@QEOR7M7Pb0gS4EwlB@4HB8KoEf4@MZFdFJb/GrEGrkkLHOShFcV00mIUGM2zVIpwFxi3Wg4mnu/GoUZ6shKufpZBo/AYOiTrhlLgoQ9DPMeyDUy7w8t96BeniH4TBxLFCxTFmcoPBO9J4dsZycywWO/x6eH7BCYXw6GG@kYivZzPjIMd5NxQql0E@yk43tCZwfseOIBkW2Qp7BqTvogqquQyfmj7aGQz@WjU@Lh/wxKvvK1TKfwTpCHIuhwWF9fD94U8X3YON6rcvkoZwKLYBQPA28Yd0bvAGwO1BsxXBVfsYSBblY2cUMKSHqsKrt8Lev0/vHQeLj67FhWLBVbgCGkLbZok2SiIPSQUsP@rQbKYEKw41q4zUAmisO@i@QzBHswEVDlTOBF@gJh6rHG5yEQiRQj0YjCycjDctIPW56Ea4sqSun@xkq5em@TEOa965SLACRV7AK0Zi7QwuCwDPDDM3Hl8ULm7wu6QOPRf880@DsIMMnp948XKDhY8zszF@rzzHGEHe1gmPQUGxiIlRUp3rMOwNHEsA7AtXy7BAciB7DOg1PhIvPRpGC@PZyjdvCGckI0iJolKIhxUauw1064tIxil7w39ZM/FyB3hcTOwNG4sCcfzxSQCDLxziEOBs5DYH9k0MMgzigFLyjLqfH@w@GiMM/74bimzjEm4WjOybmBYiAz2tJ7eLl52fS5tdC9FHKlB9Jmy4pRcUCfXk@GK@yAMPaBcCgUCSPvEp5YGdH43NvHiCVngxSjxV@IrevLbzIbgZoghJfWXSfEPfCVjcPKSTumzcqX6QS22qEmhloH64kQSMKRiCepX4vTBWCBp5U4KVrBlJwndlL40kSihGHfmdFjoDyHctZ7ziwJ9B9M@f4XO@8inJO9qrqVZNakN6YrGsWDY2TdRXdIljXpDxb2dVAZb1TxhOVFYm8es7e72CAo6Obt/z@BRxQJHFyWfqunWDftXExRIQExyiPGvPk3@RZ50CH/L4y7pF@/fyy0qFZ38P7qlg7RNEe5HdMh3gzXifHV@bSECAjuGmUvc31PNXCglBnQOmZSJeNCbOzz84eik4H5DVt1cc7SPezHqYxxxCWCvuB46Eh6JNqTwB7YJ9JzmMBYj4svjY8CBvgIiGZJzqpxx0YEY@L8awyYQ0eH6B@kBGDWITsDBxRfjQ9yZTZUowwjg@T83F4ScRwP@7/5WBBRg8WBMlBa0RirPPXjPiVCPe/7croWHezhOYGepeVhZ@PQhET@ls@4@kBUWusL/izAz4fCOoGQtH2lEE0bIECD3NjfjQ6wSD3B@HHN4x85At8eDQPUtINIMFkdNVEUCDxEmYD0yIrMImZLSa1DlHU4m0yWW5qSDKE@Nh5NZ5YF4gsnU3iMiB3xuWZWk2gY3TImaxxZX75B6myeH00zVODt39gwy9j5XHJcjzPsvBwsLfbgVBofUtX@ckdeb9RO9zzr7Zi4h3jqmNikJMy7W76VrvW0hwwdCKurUqqA@zneEkVj2lsn8FQhhdOuSl2ovLNCqj3olr2gaaT6iD2ARPhDVgGAHc6oPEa@Mr7pure4v4BgcBJBQsL0YoDerhpsJFpNselV8TJHF6ABJXdgcJ3gTCDJr0QvaW4jjpS05gw3dThp6/gTcBpmJKnsYbpQ0Pdh9Qn0CXU1JVyo4S2AgWjk9NTudJ1c6Ek2o4oxsVXLNPuEbQhuPSa8aYJbePvTxWTBLpH0TT0ETPwCoCugu/6ZvTWV8gKOe8Wqkk7bsWiDm15UGkesZIpFUjYO2KEo3Q4fqdSEJePhfjrQdfwfIdjIrvYKu1NpeQTe1qm9mTwjjm5iYLP8yfDWng515f3afhbPNLpQFrT@Jp9H/P2eND9X0D2h3Z@pNNoHrV0ZcSkW4XuYGabK6uZwhrOtbSuQWyIvQUv0Qlo7OrQwpds4sYAHMe9tLp6o@osh834RnMGAHjiDqBKobBlK92@4gFGc2sMswnc0UXz64kT/eMo09QnQzp4boKNZ9R4Mo0xeYyNTnCJUQWJKYLFuKDGQGrBz1Pc8myaFlsDR1ttDro0GOC5LC8Fno5SEk1MoMSq0WbsKTzX4AlFp4tJoR9j56/491fhfiJTYxfQzevMW6CQyiGqBXT9Ci992UuPIweCBVZ0YMDmqxowIiyzhpiMcisBQOMYxi9HRVktDAWq4YG0zb1DtNpQhnxzsReDVbTEpY4P7ilZZoE9JSAS8L4pZEy6Aiud9iwjkRq@LtXzbER4LFmNotw9NhHxUW/ZJ4e3f6HDd5@s051gjG7sJHLGyt6uernM7j1A3AOCGg7uLElGvJ0DqGHauDYz3pECpJe8WdhjaAMFyH0BkhoO2QzHpUA1@AbvOrd2CRVkOlque2tYEF7JlD1q8Lcr@@0/Xsx6wltzgSq@SO9qFq996kSlFl@IoVUSscA0UVYcvASPEHdwXGKIj3J@oIBJbhDWRDKaJnyDKi8ot7mCsECdM0lDSoINWRet73z6lGAj4cWLwwnTsJJJjCpyOYSiD88qqMagf4eTkQRPMrASCHzPVJD25RD@ihmdzTP3ezeMEiTWUZCHSFBg0IUXjqaNu0yCyfdlyrlF72HiIh70iFnen7sX69JAfGsXMBWh/zofJta@a0sJnh8uGZBD9hzZemKcGyeiX@rhyLyODhMjEB0MzyNVxawD3cI4T95RIIruKBHrNELAoB22oeC6YwNpF/VuIGONYQUmSI1RBW14/P4vVHh5t6ALZBB@jQFgMomAMENlnrJL8URmEH3DeBzjYVI3GT@w1nCW7aWficfWI/w8fRD//fiSPKJDY5hojGLevhRI0RgtEwn87Sn3M9Wl4v0W9Z0p71R9Z@jh1/cBevj1naXnT6qvbzF@SxWBIYYeOMfBKftTmFHj29m9QG6neMowMDMeobbeTaceWPi@mKnUdKH/bGrTskwH72aeXwKe55xCUHwgHPJ8yvNYAzdMkNPcfCQXM9D18Lp0J8S7uG2ivhglN74gj49foE/q3LYtxmgKQMwlsuj73uSUHzKIiaEkGOSJRL9@mBWXqVydALXtmvYXV1ggq7JfcKoon4MxSuzXPsa4N4AjUHXavgil8ZIgoWJsXpIB6h2YbjoJhs1PIqgu5ONkKqQ6m5vKa0RMLXZXepoQiR1pj8@Sxlq3FFhrapB0BnYN6BP@PNa39w7jHoPzxiBLbyTujdIwFdvrkLVtk2/EZkfCOoXHnkCFd3u2Oej2GF4UhTogwvIt5R0TtXvULkGrx5cuDvCumjVvW1x0XH3ffpxmZxaDST6dn8ee@@qIbaLi3xyhLZnbAqKBYULssFpY8HSnhbFJe4EkvQ9c54Y@bnEYZ09tFijAFvIDFOEVWuIg@2NipzkZe4NYUvY1EElxXbVvuahZa7wKWP1xMguXYcYJUQPw7vgiZWXBB51fWM7GgdJS6YLF3QdWmVfazNxC0jHU6UI2VTT1ZR4pHLciTttuoDiYO5ZmS/09tJ@fK1@9hnn/F1gTMvW4MkFwKkxycXM0KDt4NK@PL/vEmzU4p8IMHFAemDbODUeJuZhv0R5HvUu5hbkXTZURLp4SxenBfPYGNxrNTU0rbj0FmoqODiAiKAGpVnztDNfL8N1cmPoVTUf9xHwC7JAqh/fO8mKYLVxl9hLPUsI2W6radlBlVZBXqJxRPN4guqu3StjWlC7OEGGm7olerzhkj6bZYk9r8VMZm0dYFFv9ONBsPtnG0qSgLWnfD7DCZk9tXRMsvmtmjD2pGUkgm@EmzQ5zPg4UG00Ops3iESckZDwfaY7FTpxpPUoIqPIEMHFeZVYJCQCj@olXQU6xlWevQ1ONJ/Nosw6@LiLiiFdBCJsRveA1YPtBq0mKgbzyDTIwPOvihK7mEJ7A9DvBOgMdZbFppTAOJeFkZYM@VCybixV@ieFENQOeCSAuWCdjAxjFNhTbxxClYVyMxFzSfBm8NAONWT0AnOTQ/hwrQF@faEDKCbpNLO/QoaCx/QKiyX4eRX5zPJgO7rWwVTGFwDSZWIIymUVLQ/EsVsM0kkHMHGwWMcAhWOxr26/yn6n9GCpABsoeEDB4/B0tjC0FjZVUdDH7hJ5OtURGFlUBOdAf6K5iqObA0Ue/b0YILdArF4XuDEEj8r4T3kl1HKdhfHaWxpcBsL30IW13w70JOFEH4Z3dX8MY6VSIGmy4vinGWaaLYzBOwnv5Ey4TRU8xbl/E4eDo7QmYisErE9DSg9sEXDrjleDbBkB00nExw01ROm@DndJyByREeyZursA9pQO0B@EeDxuPiFGToMDGuiBy01Jtnhlw28gcMG98Bn4dX/UJAnJ816YGmYqhj/CjbMZqId/zgQTwIO4AKtxy2FUDaUD8QsEBnGxHUG5veGuqwkaBgxtf3cIXKmIOlC08EbfGz8CNM/zJufFVOLT5YpaIeypdBq8VgM4WsJLxffbRRTG/j3kT/an9T6Qye7YuD5YzlNjbjysJtKti1iznTWC1Mm20iGoV3KmxjicsoF8C6IVWX6zgWgvftUG2M2zFW2AQVbFbPagStJeGDOPaRKe21iaywRwOzd7@VeYOA/QVzJUr0Mag38QraTpEL/@YJq17oJEcQKJj1DHKeXz0UiMJp8WBny9xqyfZj9sxv2/xrGhegpMfAPTtSDiCijKR/VIQBv3jnU0@dTpR4UVTSBbJgv4LEYjXlIj76GeisnXv5np/ypctT2OUH8EYGxvPpo6EocHLDWxxujXta75yhGY3kvyuopHdG9cC@YZlTORZ9HCR3xnH8ZUMzzg3fq0J9WccWHqK@2Ujr8dNLghFnR/o4QenxgTma3jl8aZlfzdyhvMWiLAWt0ClRRTujOJp@colF@w@83hrrtyGyM8GZYJHtwStK8GuwNtamDL5uTZb7wjtaoI3BKTgCIT2So7md2GS9PJIEhqC4oXncxwqfLzigZXFcadkMOQep/@8nB75BK@oRjXj9UbOH5UK545xHv4m4VZgq@6yd7yB7yebID@9@7Tiv8Dhp9GNJAY3p5bZUOzvopNWQ77Da2Fq/s14jS9QJV1YGH0LdYgW/jbxsU1eIm4W3YDmHf5mwCznjalZnicYO7zrzzmqIjZ58tcdwPDO8GUK4vgGeIPGcMeN@cv1ooM6bspxiXcCI32SSx/g73n9TtEdU1xlRgMrT@TQeuG3rcR4PZBnL/pdc9DBouBKP6QZH1CZPZ2y2PFFDm3N5Qv@nFIETvsOB4iD9/9YYLegd6E@P7UCUHRkRazwi4QXnk0c0Ytt1B1hI@M1YMsNka2og3eFEVaCFrwD19nQrOq5rXbhcaxhidpOBPUlf@U7FdrixsSjw72D0@3j/7e9J22O47juM/dXNAeUdhZ7L8ELiwFBEqCFhCQYAJTsAlerPWaBIffyziyxK3BVce5UUqlyrNixYzuVw04q@Zqk7Lgq@ZDv8n/wL/A/cN7R3dMzOwOAkixXUqJK5E7369fX6@73ut/R3N95d2f/YIdKkiK/Niiejst0U@afonPvocSb9SMOcTLvTTw4x/HEoThLKIEfdEZBIB6CuOuCOP6yBSVbUzeT@uZee5Se98x3J@tc/pCZeTK@J01j30MToSmqKkH/TlkA5@dh288x8cMZSA6pUOu1j54MOC5UBvdM2Mw5B/dPXEntEcV8JQhp2YBHyqgXnCIHKKWJ6BsznDT9LqxmtyR1bBU0XjmE/hK0QwRkACAftW7nJQo0ba5VGHgXeE5kI7GtHAoWZO8HFfGUq92masU29wt5yFZ/NDzOSO8JRguIc4NDq4BhrNfVEJNREFSBegvoKRBHmnvEHSqjfFCulirlz8@lQfiI/RvyVvApTPI/pZ33sp1@YvykJLN9FQPA4HEWMRu6SNikRAu65GhNUYO6WEU1WdGnMydPtyaX6K//hi3IUwzIZevWvhij8c/XnvvSZtaf2cfCF2@Gk0jAEascRb6JKqaLz89g5/@K1cibmYtcZEXxpelEsumEDKj2JsYT2dUsaR8j57G7xxf2eNWkr398pd0twxnFeDK1a0UUbXUEm6jSfBiPRmoiX06JPqJBH1Er/7Wpw6f3NcEWIOxustrxG/TaMI6IdLTyRprwOlDPBSruprb@ItJ@Va@pto8q7ZM58p7hRRquOdncqIo07TavX4uIGjhburCOL5G/1DDX5i3KqbxxGaeU0eXZoe7MuGRM/Z0vBRNK6yBvgYyRxeG1oiHmJLWaNokSrlKPKMRLOSqncC2Wxy@mth6OYHhZSk7EzEt82VZ7FccGA1HR2YC2B7n4HEVQhpexaSijU6PmIq0yudCWbEL0C/z/F2srTYJs4PGlkdVv0MjqS6uRL61GvrQaOc9qZOVqeepPym1vWAbWrC@Kp8D9Z1ZgQW3viffeuXcoDt/ZEQ@fPfht8bW9Z@K9e08gZU88fXb/0e4DAf/vPDnYEVRA/3nXnaDKvYCp33Y7Lt3O1yqVNUGYlwKUr4mD1kC8M@q4r4B4NvzWYOuEP0pDN9jkUjuv3Ml8xM9BY1RmCaTVBN0V8VuTunFCi@s2UPIA3xGVL09sI3nz9PlmiWwvKBy6NuDmtz3iQUiPi56VtNEGwI8gFdC0@EmWdKfxaZ2Ylm5JyIHTf954BIEpfHwg7j3Zxkif27uHu3tPDsTDvX34fPo1dLMjtnfRbcz9Z5hFgI/3tncf7j64RwncgEpJ4N0aGayf14QSgtOodF72phgerI9SofyKePVeyWSGI2UV4YvsdBi67@kCSeG7Ozs7rZOLdvvavf2vvItcjft1YVkY5NJwqC4tEK5V0GgEapNRtOvsTB1Zy2KVN6TBXFzD7HqG7oDod0Eo5Dl6J/ZcYT3Aa0R8kKa42cywKdRQ0VXAjaiUI1hHUASGbLawQSg3oTa6PVC14cVqT31g0S3pmBXlyBXlpdUnpBiccXfY4TC6KgHonrW6qdpgwgB4ISQTGADvYDAhaL10d/GSRNyQENMABX9IuMkJLwbjh6fINaKBq0y4z4FAbss28bzRlGKAo5Y35HmMmDXx7kAxUqiIT/DoJKffV1eupBIH/L98Y8NXWYC0YBfswcpWQkX47AbUAHv7SasX@MJ2cngbDCKIO/RYU@u43wJxj@6FJ2iw9ArVCKja2w7@2VSO6hXDSYE4lQjTnotoO3S5bXnwu5ctByXvL9WIenvUaVSYkvGfLmzA/aUGfBo0gKho7hfoVmgcEGNLaEY9Scq2PwKKBJFPfBSNajTqTjtupICUdewX3ocf5uQgF8IihooPtU5r2GGoB3wIOUUfVOTmAoQY0pQ8wdconkM72oPwbXiAyhATbOAHanBlbabwoGqUmjiyUuTnU2ptt8gY7sJaieJZN1hvX2PtM4qev302y6NnkjaKyVqa89GfMyoxoGenCbp56QlULJoH1BIO7pAJ946PhF8@ev@2s7l9/3nxow8KjXL5mLeFVpcfL1gpkZ9ZSCSH5aF1J0kbUK00iTTjT9tYWukz8m6Jq1whA8blxAPme6tZ13l8rbqcPqR4WdF0Snz92uFSRbI3IRLCSDLh7lYQR6rKApVpiJxEEO6d0Fj0rKtSCoRT79dbGNceZ6EOIzLEfYTUa8ywaqRfY3i7xgc92Fkykk/j6db4cyoWuaQo@mOb81F@377v5DdzZQVFi0kPp6226ILCXM3JXi1weum8WkK3fT462L8vj@72ua3j4@GNsG2fi@2N2lbMp@PiY8nAdXm0H52Dlg@3T4UW@l5IR8yH5DI2TemaOAvXVhTNX1DjB0tzR2sP0ODZixFVNVKjtumwjx7ibL4Uh6ZRgZyJJmSIDg63d/b3hbWDt2zrUBb2vdawQ/aluA0i7qvK0xHbIdNmV9JMkw4TpJknlbJg89Jotect5sTBS9kqJA9SkOOhNwsdtRckk5m0juCThVgINLzmDVGNXLR1Z2oP8o8k4sURakKJcNKMDmYSu7nChw872adNJhy3AvPG/ktvrJkZdyadddFV9WRuIlKMMB4HrWN8@U6ev/eYP15X9TCD5X59Sh1GJfwO@ssXB1DxGF@KS9EZPGda1JSSzgpR6YoaOzLLi3LYn52gdCz2heSFjW1dMseyacwfXzMi2RF/uoXv/HOZ2RnI@061xVPKhjmhufDQs6NHEDCZIAaLLZMqoHhjIY8wGg19TjqaITfX2jVqzZFqJUUzk7jr6UBvAQd/42Z8e4hXBbvtuVUVP5@q@JSI1GTE3VquQWUC5ps3bly/CHe8F6p48bPi5jMkvn8Gg/GrloHSn/ukKgSUu/ukoPJDAjhn6ByQAru2WjCxgsDqJJwpkb7TYWS2D9pyOkFbPGjM3rPDAt4XxWvNiVmsbcnY@UQysRPIUh@MJaw7yqtmafQX51d3n4K6XVDf1TevjxcbAuF9@OJXHCZzfzTGrRIY8UmTvaKCSL7uo1ZcgCU4@KD29GvEwNxScSyPON7cFr9wo40017gVjF6iXr@KnCljm1n4DFUatMZnr/GC6zVdmXIe2gTIsl5BbL1gHRWOrLnVHZESQU@HstziVkbTYJt/1TSDb66j@iDlMYDxgOnoAcy@nRUg96zjrYIKNZnNcxrwJzqpyElAqwHKHjp9ldPRLsEb9@c6vczpXRcDz@nUDYnltKUjXmY3JWQ8QmbWksB0V@v15k0adp19l7OBjdFJb8nGgGzZH@nUq5yKOlUq6UiWnYZJDU4CSUonrUgoPJi8wKQl33VfNmmSZbQ5QJgtiKHXb5Sk/tRdW8qOOWnCEfBEQnl32M3QpFDMU41KHQlb6FpWktDRltcokQKl3IBQJgsnlhfSlhcWMIEh3Qh9yUTFxagB@LdshGyqSbxY89HWC6Twiet3pq7YmaGMr2IjKqokxyArYufJtth7KPb3nu5EUWOLm8ijUCmlsEehmGXDqDtqyRZgwkfT4KTJieoznnvqcq5Cwd8aaDiaGED8Gc9VFRCKBi5Lcfa6@1ocweE91pNid3MNOemqx7oPpc5oOgzOXs9e0/TOgNMrAQncFYsSXhLcXRoWuRIlh63Igd7iMCwk8pVN5VYhrIVSqJaZ9M0xkhbXsTWfW0hsGb1/wtTByqRNOgzICdsk7gQjZHnWZXxLGI7OSRhwk96yHWHb8YbhoVQqLSXnxS0duNE1I@5GK7tkJfm0Su6ElTCFaTwlH@OIhrXlRHckXnuvVWXhoYJH/@24tKNHG303y2k0jhhadhGYSsPI5lcJo8/dTPTX0oKTMyii8Ubl6wYvCAzyHu7mDtN4BIzoewlMbw4KjBfQEhytggggL5MlQCq/jLGZ3Mpw6SUUSW5xuB6Xm5NSS4guoUhyLWGjo1MRrvXYbHRGwJ1xQBL80QRB0DhfE2cOyGap4rTFKuIFJSmSONPkOm3@J5dQh9qmGQLosaF@VhtseiOyZrFz4aMjYrZAdt4YENyDyJ0KHmtmejWebh5JYtMoHocwGhUDBpyxk@riuWBPIpGkU7TU4mVFRlsyGjjyWvJohC2nYYASCaWAFqOgvGpCWABFEOLi8GQxQHklRkHzyaAG8RO8iTXWVmM1atB8MqixPpawFpOwRkHzcdClfY02yujYa4Z21T5/8nIpfKyJzqjKnbmdacAnjXJaAWsogOVhMloSuusde8FdETJa9KsE7UGiXbstPWKrNBDwb9zSrA8VUKy22QRZbYgQdwuDl/ISKubrKJN9CxlzzTxG4DnENb6PG6BHBGFOg2APTLIhismQAo06xRQrZg4Nl5oFok7GSMISK2fwuUDu92jljMUdjvxuFazcwuJm1SO7KPRJJUv5aGNDjUUpGDU9kfinLhtPOEZjEcVRCpPO@RPBMQ10Kl5xFPqjDl92FhBXXQlrR5COAjg97MRw4GvKcl9UQUDTuLgd@KCyjAObkBfndcrEoYSqZRyrl8ahBLZlHMXLt4PkqaS@vHVpHCwIJuEoXxoHUuDymForZ4BgwX9bSaQWGQ80i5KprUI7ShoaZyvy1Y73RYmqAu0FCUMEfhb7SmqHZMxNWu8bYtClxgOFjuXxsD1eSZtwFNPOXeEL5iqWzC2tFxZuKZVvYI2VVxfX/KALB0Gp19frO2Hxx0T02CWJREj3HijElDonExCRcDZLUvpQDAjhhPY3m6ia1WzSzdDT/b2v7N973Hxy7zEKUSu8R@H1DWrLkLpOpVTDePZ829IknSJHoKoFdiND@7CRR@2TaHboFKHIsVhq5cyAW1jMQGFNDt0XlYbuqXgIWRS0fgknQpb03QxMj01t0Ju6VXxl5UJI8wRTvZLy2ia0hGCYTmRLCMZIzhjCFpd/PmQNlefD5wEDtsUR22T6DbO9z9FwySgoRPHV8@Bdd9JGXZKidlrKs4gq@Ci7kXMqVLmQN@ghBmMCf1Uui/vKKa60X2v1O@jydtojx7cDr98atLut0vhknOn5jnRPY2d7Pjq5zKAy1e7hzv5B8ynG6dp5QJYT@KdOeYe7j3f2nh1izgFkXZfJO/v7e/tNUlDff/b0ED2GxpIsE1BiCcFkQgToyd479x4ZMPxtyUayQYgP8ib8I135FIQ3bs7o7zmZeRRYFaJJQXjITAWLUlpBBN7AHU1V8Db0P6EO@AJanuCjDNSlohqTQxobrz9lXujrdGFAUTsm03FAoKQBb8dGIhctwTAD/xgLkC8iH/h20qYv8Y0y5qEh32hsx8qigQwWy0j7rp5PqwOXycF82LEVOunIs3DmDgESX5uy06BXvJ1d5NCr5JiUhuKFs2U4OcrkHDWbXFKOoNRKzxhBjMxr13pGGbwDFFmU0CSElilUgF8Q6yKf93JnGTNAlMyCXZXjR50Jw4Y@CiPj11wx5ojdmrKeL9SPBKJ/SQscTSP8@dR8lCICk@9TZMxxhJbneszoX9VZvmG29ezY9D4V2nWXUHvkATT4XmCzoxfy2RfSnXzukg1oYkZ8xqN5gF6@jckOU4VM435Qh4EKJnPBFoR@oIcLet7Av2fStWsHFWhsILicCWtZnMvuKNFIyA8YgMQ8a9NaD93YsFmCVhxmiA0TopoE8b4JUUuCeGVCXE@C@ORjBvF6dj6vJm9T1G7cYG3myHwmFP83XbxYVLAbShU6LAz4zOLqNGYkO4xDQucdNAc1z2xAbrbs5rkti6L@5N8Bt4lLlipSJdzwc5p9Duaf/561zjd0lxilv@YeGhsUMifyyYtNmPG@8IEkcdUkaUsax/aTc7BZlprF5LLfDSni/RSi@eSnEZhksvm2mnehx0@9cF0Jy1ZDq4Y4gv9YRuC8CYIml1fri7yNsgEvZtfWNRbVgxABg1w3QWpxkKQqX59bZcXEV02ssmqCVC5T5Sc/k3XK8ysB4ocagvZaOZiJoP8VWWikmg@FkkB9hkSbmqfhq28q@HG0DWaxJPCnIXYq0ji/3T//RrzdYclE@N9PJE4qYNKXmvbEgf@Hy@K4norjA0ZRLKaOW5Yh8vlUiE9@FLaDhze@zM5bJD//w4tLV9JL/25YOjzmN9XBzVyDQhbfArV6UDSTih5pbDx/MAA6JaE1xjGq15yx5PAslgZj0Q5Udba0OItm11T2PDH7us6OIV8wg6W4JPSvR4zRBkcYJNYo/E1WvsxwqcxNx@Tactwhk9tlZl0amMPYaB5HmuIYTM9mTOBYjQgZy6hlbk4ye4sMccH1ROHHb01aJ8MWBmj1R8OSjADijco7g9ELDw@qSRndXJRe@GnS0GdhrQkByXEOiq/3UKECmiqdirDuN8vtCNjqdKaDaR/f0BwpV6FjpHIZXcaRIDicDnyJE0/c@1OvDz1wkFMLWUQQ88bQSjqFgZW@VPWxqpOqXa6yXGa98RK5oaMkaltn4o0DqsxZlgXQ5RMxqFCFt2HAKhYeDdTPCBG7onVkfx55Q9c24DGKq1cwEsgvQt7hUnWijPiYGDgKqAHyZDqIYDiTM066MQ7nlHy0@LErhRqOnIt0IyYuRgjR1hGeL2rSBx25lkEk0oJoEsVSK6zleJQI0VMgz0EUYq1Qq2BFY8wiF0XkGVprlrd65LaIjFoJB2HT0DQLwBGG6OW4blagd5Ch2@VYv/zbj//Oyp2VyyqNYup4wxbIDBSRJMSKn4ejp@rbQI/yibRVjOH@@xA3o@66HW/Qwgg1gYEaiCsFM0wgYj4DQkOnVaM@7DejY9vwBaMqRMIql@9tb4vDd/b33kNrKL5EICqIFUciWBdWnoedSkbypWIwgkhKWIZ5LCtGINWIZSjdKwTTPSb3Oj3b0MCC0frmH9No0V3@CDXdeV3GEGK2xU598J4QdWtNtHoiFAXjPHzzjxjzaMzas8mIR2NLEib8HLtA/Ooq0l7qF0Mk1/eL7/8ZVSctSoDnw3uVgVl1GtNPuUfyQpZotlhtpPYqUg0NQiriC4foWz8mZD4H6VYbYeaKuStqJMnd/uFfCcKBjw8we0ZJEcGTvxDRtxmRfj2gkUvFV7wQ33cYX9ejVwATUXse7eJjOCdLEzQaso3k8gXD94vvyxYDvBfgm8k5daxGmptJnIx/NWeWysrpSJtfA3/qDP/ARCrNXNMw8kGViOfjn4XL1Owmu05m@r5irM5Y0xI7/PF/JlEf6ZjD6kEP4IzWnKrEtZLS5r/4S41/lrkyu4Bgfvm33/tR2MdZas9mqf35XriaZsu9mKW1/UpsS/oqHhlWfpY6FT@NVhNZuTPH@ExD8JO0cZ9FB3uWtuSB9PWin12w7NOQfFsh0Qt@duGST8P1HYUrcbHHu5Wy3Gepy1xhT1noMfyrKc2Exfgv5mKcnTfzqWs@nSz@hpAjw4fGo0vTUi5LDqdCrO2GqNK/6JkX/92Mt8bc/fCqLWRcHOCoAB1KTRHaQ6jZhrnyz@Ix5RfM14SpVelsQfXIqKUqawHRpNX3E6pynM@trhoOHYh7CbVsfrpKMotyeeiy0f103EWpg97vBiR5TOj5D4MHJO@M36C5BG4bxBW2tiH3BEfU5Aa94PhL5IPoyOeQEjXQA3QXxA36d0N3t1jlFJI3rsSx9EfMEl2h63QUhVIFESlJ5KuNRKGC5dTEhfBPegdi6arN0hUOluwj@ZENcy7cvL/1I70j6VEaRbHHUOYvxvmPchpIxYjeysljh@Tp0lE7kS8tSEVT1RGQenT/s7lbxKpL5yUNsDTM3/0TfdC5PuqydqE/aPJKHv8xOCYOTOoJaOyf/JMQ2LnVcMtIrflP1cT7vEOlVY4n2SXqSanmx39gIWknDxJn1y8WsiTGVBlL7D4Rzw529sXes8Onzw7xQsZ0jKhl8HRBj8Vu3pdJgI1eEizJsnUQ82sszhp5TF5ewcvXctT9P/8edp/R5h2rYhnDdG65H0TKVVW5c8aIpuLSIyTHZ6k8X1pA67hu2VvHuS1HCATo3WGA69V34YcE44sJdvgszzYmfzaZNqVuWTHjucTUf57dMi5j0i8T8KjDCXCqAufPqXxJGV8MZdCV1Rxf75yk1zzGD71QLj8J9IumoMjNZvKF7@npaamH4ammE6/k@uieyEfHcOXxMTALwxFdaqLbbCA8rwOyLTovnHZehr@KndbwVctHBZm7M1SJdu68Ped/M2l3xOPjAYfi@LT3xELQbW9hXugUAFmh3XlZ6J126zKDDYO1wgknIvczUR8DX/3yxj0NMQrwnl1ntfsvO6M@cbtWuw8HmRVWzT1UkHP1Kb/HHhvGqEvkufR@KohptlmRQuCjAeXAT@CqlHWxNzuaNyLFZ7p4RJvF54iY5yJlhWDMZz0OChsw4/xZWKmq9mgmncVrEzJ8fUClEAWJaOYKJmIRjjkzVorfxBcqTEPIeSQNLX86DpVW481fMI@OIgygiTEMuGuXj95/fvS8MfTd09VGvnxcQEdHCN2WZo00puSzh3/j6Pdf9ccjP5I0dP2AFVwqKqlzIqmBaYUVX@RYxTRuoFla4cYLBw21Ax3KxC36XmB70kyVtHFO6HnbOrLCMeaGHcnG4Eh7SslApuHDk2FqbyJqGIgwXXdJReJL0oWy3pugPy0FW4QxRwcwwzmaEWKghuhSkTFMxSLaKnwt4wQYdvaBG@uKyoepOIplGd1cyPk3m3/1jZvfg3WR3HoiWN4UY0pjMxc2XFcuF/aIuekY8wotKK@2@ujyz9oZknsapTiYq6@WlWkK14NdkEFnjcnvSMcT/JI6lFooWNccZV8xd3hZ8rpQQ6o1TcJXeMpXhCDL8wbCEUQSirmy2MwsBpIubxz0LJZU7NRo5IwaOeMiDD1LaWRDFsNAnqbbhgY6bWvBeQT4qqzRS2Kh8FuvMD4VuyJaLes6wz2HqEBZGMKEIp11Gom1HxmNNjatGAIkxCUEXbfXmvaD9Ux8w6sW9Zfeo3go1R7FX5IMeK8AAqMtuM5KZbYmMvligVfpHrm9hF9HGataqBSq9F@F/7cKKlH9X11OrEQhq9HESiH2368lsYEjmywWVStruCFnfrUixvPgZDSsZVaEPrMFndnoj5BfUF/4/D7sD73x2A0ozJE4dof4uI2BX70R3lig8y@MqwO/X7rkX2RdIRf8FNt84TcRUVMiKo3nwrq2ZcG4D8ajSSA@7Htt9RtjlN9cU1/@3Ec3Ur7rEg/kAxMkn7lR3/dwMt8N9oZ4L1FGj8nBiH@3@6N2eQCivDshV44@rHmA8EalyXRYJndT7rCLz@JkhtB6CU07geqga90mgDWxW3YOKc930T2l9XzW61nkvMXtdw9cZNzw9kjoSCq7XeI7Wv6JhdvaingCTNg6u1tRPky0ly4acVdk5WNcsc/xnEljIGtE@kKNd4xlSZoZFipFy/d6cv1nlegBGkpZOWLL7BydiKMghFeqnLIAK4ZESmAfMUgfM8Z4VoQ9whChLlqWyEbkhZAJ1I7wU1YaJlBF8nz2CsAeYq@UFa1rw7Qyz1hdR/eeeFfmVHN6p/DQTqp6ex1jc1BPcEBxmuTTcPU25pCDSl9gxDn2TWP2I@/IlgAgTwgFQgQee4IeGdovSIkUL@vg8ED6K6k8vJ5oo0u0PsV4wfuroXtMUVLEadvjUDBdzycALFk@/tAbyyEqREi1PT0GVpvWAkVW8Xx/6t64dXuNGkRxjRRod9SJgNbKgBldy5apcSfBoK97cSc4EX33ldtn/2/cbIr9wouS6MyW2ydeN9/MEenAUEZ6CqNg3ylw2vbOw0f3Dne2C6JYvYHgbKCqYW1jcDk7T/lkwCHJCIvw8i21b64xkdt@IbtVzuZk07fMYc@bDVYIYM@aoBw3trMOFZM3c4wYRKYu7lUFHW9Rx3ZDXW1cbtiU6QSjFlhqcNXKX1mxkKSxrhUkwcjmCGVy4aEBX7DxLAGl7hUwAnJ3a6IQhqGEiHKtjavFol5T6/SrCBtrsbjJdubWA5DDX4rs/nQY2W2ztHZaIgubHHrL463tapb2hZJVFydO9i0/W0fuXHNOr@xp7kyF@Bv2sBU2D9zh6P5czZ89VVorMCC5o2ojl5MJ2f/5bxD7FqFZQN8OcmfIX3/oKJewJd7Ud9iDpp3l22Ao9mEpcGfBA9pcAyeo6wLtUXdeopCk3Qdw9nbtD806xnbujLSbO45zPXcGVU7GaIcyhs3QPQSMuTqm9SJpocjx/PkQ3eKuovz11ceP3oEp30f/Un5w9H5j9Vq5kM3CEU8aSA5G@hDbe4@f4k3CJFeiG4WHk9FAjsukpSsp4cM@Wg5T6wsWdq2MqxB2zmM3kL33788PW8dPWgOQmFswBNELnJap9YNh7lGX3xwjx4pOrpU7O3YI6mTi9urMCS1855V9nKsH8M@JWcUNqMKp1Qh7AIUcdCAQG3VvCKf1O4ePHznZjZZArE7Cqsjm25o4gFCIYGxMIoE2QjoYThepKmC7TSIY@JPPWpvRvmyUW5vZ@mKR2p5Ho1aXPX5lQwLu2tOCpLiJszyl9UlIBfOx62ACH21f2Tm0ClAWZV9MpBhHc9q02Bmxo@pgcsOdgo7A@QHCOM7a229TGhaZ@o5Tq1RyqB6yAGzkAwLQ8sKa1BeTltO19UC2xl6Jrs7dGddFzEmtVCu3hv4psKPl6s3KneuVu6MJvht0Xb/ztg9biNPCkLJeMH8bDflJnex41O@93fP6@GB1dW319p53/3e@eufg5rbdaf8W8JDWC3@ED/iTsdkANZPsrLx8/dadO5Xr3Xb19p1epV1ruVX4dru9Xu2m6966frM4br0clQakGGgxaSPK3jkoa70blbXWTfdOZa12q1u9Xbt1q91tud21m7Ve9WavUzSYqhBlBvY/tS3i1h7fIN9K570yS1uvLJ37Xw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPSoqoqoq                                                 # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZJfJfJfKzKzKz     #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOx\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ _ye{--}besizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]=x 3 8[]p#s4;93
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001298 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9624 bytes)

Run the code snippet for a TIO link.

**Warning**: TIO link hangs Firefox 54, works fine in Chrome 66.

TemplAt code is:

```
<attache>



Print[194]

Exit[]

</attache>
```

Retina had some spacing requirements with this answer, particularly with the empty brackets on the exit statement, hence the blank line in the middle. The `P` in the print statement also affected Alphuck, so I decided to place the code prior to Mornington Crescent, and to remove one of the many preceding `p`’s in this location. Retina’s line requirements in this space also asked for an extra line prior to the TemplAt code, so I chose to move the first line of Mornington Crescent into this line. 
Finially, Cubix sized up to the next cube on this answer and is now prone to break if code is added to the top third-ish of the polyglot as the IP both wrapping and redirecting down. But what else is new. :)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 9):

## 195. [ZL](http://zl-lang.org/), 9540 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJTFZmUiJLpQ8940Wv2@MHezw7GHvW7p7xLnYeDOxgsQ9reIAF1q/GwL/hm6fFYIH@B73nnIi88CJV1dfdXi9gSmTG5cSJiBMnTpw4ccmmYvd@85swftiRqY@7uukwR7Ud1ra0G9VKsY0xe6Zodj6bC4UQqmZ1h33VcOy1UJjJjGlGS2uDnznmtWpon1QLwrOMDSyzayl95vQUh6l2SxmoNjOHzmDoMLMzP1mOse2@eaUlMWVfM7oA5qjWwFIdil9h7MzQlX6zrUzF5KcyHFgQb7MtVf/c/@ywltnvK0bbBsgCY69My1YRvqXatonJVxkbbautKaRFAFUszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqAx0dcSUpu1YSsvRTANpkmEnB2cnR1MpZJm9Od3ZmQ7NspdJ02A7w9b1dFSOnVm2oivT@FdYbeiYe850eJ7VuqqhsGyqlMpORxbYhqXMJFlllqq0O5qupqBBWJL1VH2gWgxDWMe02B4USS9miplGzU@ZamHaoh85jbbE9FzOmapPNgOEN62eakAJM9ORshc5FZH1ItoaZaBYYxa1e6YFfGSxoa222a1ptYG5DH0cS0B6NvrEmoqtFlYQQc5DcG2YtwYwkWNC0zbHjsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZuD8XRoib3S9uexcy7DO8Km2YbWmIqT2ZECQZTNJOFz2cle0ILWhc7MrmwoWFtltqENBqrDI4FXVIuiITXTNeOad/Ajy2wPW9j5nJ4KeWOHRX6wQy1IVWUDISZS6GBh4iAOBiU4MftqsLw2M1RoIHugtrSO1uKMpY4c1bChyHaKaVCJW03XWVvVIYGPvZVgtonN6wc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjrcGA8SioBRRpJ1NkKlKPfYJ4vWez0aDPbK0P0U7L7HRUlX1SBz1IHmqbIQaf1mCqWp5vSQUYQ3VJow5AICBpTKQ00Mml0K2lAGktW9DA0fpAWM2J2ExVbA0FKiSxVaNNVB14otZkygTLsxsNOjxUfWgRblu1qMsRXuielgooFa@Zo7eW5jjUa1iNHamKxU4tVY1Nit2JLCEzE3NwsCIpatT19cj24U4EGpenSCkDaEwrd/r6RUhhqQpbapThW5Gkcmj7YIvdLV2im0tZYICBFVVirPIDs9OXlyp8R3Iz3bXuQ4A1BFTRWdocOGklOYACJh0oYFpBJ7qSN9nUQA9kzNan2iLAchyqDa0Bwoe9SVDNWkPLwpHEJ6pyDZXWTaML9ITKWkMD6WGwQgaaoGXCQJBg6g1QDSQvtRHIBaTwaU@DRrOxSQIdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1THxIcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9oZ1FE3HJBCPqHipLdUe6g6mGRptbHkY79R2irnFoA5rAR/fQHYKIKUAYP1@oF9SoQAYGsKkqmLUj//0z9vdLuCptVog2wS7vmFts0Ujt0KFheGQIcOCQNWpWACXwNx5csjgRtG1NgkIxRiLLKgQlOutOdTbzIQMrVsNemlPuYGeDZ2r5aicyflgn2B95ZpLE41zLlS8rzShYSkDypuqnWTPNqGVWmooTDyT7A@dTpElB9ssYqe/jz5diz5dvFShcLFUbHkpne6WgeFSyxQEvshjnPOmNiEpbUexTa0dGoydnmlkWbLFpFbFHKhGNDKBI5KIWM1ILIVSLhora5VWqqMZ7WhkHXixChlHYuVWpXWhrdXLU8mDWQKaW0SD3VWNtmJSCEQOdYqbdB@keQoGhzdJ4QrEmXYDSY7RqUAwEmY67IYHhEnZQb40kUFADqVsXVUH0UxKjqGYQLi59caIeTWdwiEqvKbV45FwJB6sOmGAmk5UFDvrqWai2NIHPRy0gCiGPYCRwELebcFIjZLR1hzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEUnFI9/iIuiTvcpg@iYJSYPC70GRPVtuBjgxCAPqyY89IY928hQypTDjMgOgwMFOlC00DiXlFarwiPCcKmawSVzQAW1NlxWRTg06A3Q1kuuD5QN0APJflMICNd5KA7OkrY8DS4sOq32GY1oG@1AfxANpQS0WZA8JH5QMKZjKk/meDjo3adiaZzecn@9hMF3OsdC35HoT0p/SjPQkrH@xMKGhYR71lumJ0h0pX5ZoYU1otdeAIQQU1sR0QRdPjDQUmxeCZsnuhpWfTedMg4qoWfh4o5HnriaFQQekiFP0kqDMqU8RUBTRHC8SSPp7OHQBupjKXPiDIRAE@SA8UwdUAgMnUkdoaOiDVgIFve1qrBzyLpTO4XOSD0HT2EBTMHSR7suNljYWRq0@yoVTaC8JiPIgiiS06iwcGV0RVnQigxg8GPI5ZsftzEJteEWEgCISm0koKeO8LOPumYc5BCoT00CLIZAxvB9DETlChhIHLVbuos3paptdE0GY4EWgj//UcZ2CvwTihOb1hMwWckj61xnvOoYHMknasseaY3N3UzSaIZRv6Z9rNId0aNrXRVIUozGvDKzt0AwpYx2YVGLk/DoHropGODQKTwjcROBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2bRPEOCJWTsdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKo8um2UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6T/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyNrkSpI9sXFp@BaR9dTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdlCJBLoy9oBQYVo/cX7iYR7E6NtsIR6VP2iCqXKyt5eoJ5UIWzyw@YyDqQLIBdBIfgCcSq1TQGYtJ1VuoaKrZmaz9Jkrnk5alDQQRXig3CvcLKuSIDFp/gNNISy3jIPs4TfoVC0ZBUFpbvagVubzIXNYv7y7b8cv7SAJTx8pKpQmVgvyi/VTXMocwXMYuVtaScj0Wu8jBINmsRDKR5Wi0mNQhIyUW@64Yiyuc2tGIClI7enkZAaIK@ly0ehbhGyWysZhHKigHDsygE0Yjqbsi5N@M1WPxCKSNRRIwxahEIkCZFhLBpkojZ04Q6PD4JSfMZjweIjY0rWv8zoh9CEvBBIsn3wH@3TyZnPb2r0G6spatoyqStLg2At70Mg9s08PTuNbYHmmsBgy3UAMYbdvezAhn48aQ9GdSbs1gRjQdRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOIO9oIJgjQ78euIoTjN@pCmzDhNHU1dU6qicSg4@C0V03N1YaO@LCSatk@D4DeA86BrrSgY0@iu5TYJSAEPk@n58fEyjOIp1UlmtV8qY4wsLQUA@nX1khrH2p2D8kLmhVOJawOUBVVdtANVKLaHmvBmN8FSqsjzeE6PPDRCSbZVexoDLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5doAaDg3WzDfUUFzwFg@eWTbxo1mmQYSObUNqIHhy9gGU8jnkRfYqFbby249TN95yIFiM8FygLZBrNPEbdktljZM3eyabBkAkDVTKc7YewaaSkDnc2B6yWztExGo1jWN8RQPqjjc26gjyoWcp30rCJkm@NQVyBo2v9I@wAN1Ptl7vw0jhJzPZKD8ri9DH6@SASzTdcTAFvMBhMlWR77BlnyvDnrjCYMS8gefRQI/mSrvmHxer8CACqUSPfwTJQ12ch4C/dyNaruueXXfJg0JTRnBWcZE7UEZhH4qqsO7DdQwPBWMoS4pJpDONLjfvjsgO097QzWktnomky5Bw8hWWbqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UiZcxLJkzIIcccglbXVnWtrzl7ZO7SDVRd/GHZjUWrnY/gSFOdkJhv@OIVTVK@rDW6HH57hAOSHVLpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHtpWWteawMFttdEHxVNXbYlNf8LsWAVkIv2na/3YNJ0Kb65rnX3xE8Y0bvL9rcb@3sZx7fgdLwShsbX@UFewKGtLUwCY/ISi3V4VsAN2LLPvaeS2aIilHJJenbD54/RUxK5g7FBY/APhBQzvoxU/1Qp1Wy2WNLnXCxSAqwiIln0aw7rxOEKSpd8LFJBFQonW/pTVdANLGOjZ@Scs4D66efEPJxKY7@TMPSK3jaE9CNTsTpYp/MbpdHDU9oKzFHydRFbX/eAcBfN1gkkLvSDLTNRcYA/fCuHj6wtz8c1EzQX28OU5PlyXmI9uKmYeqIesQMhwHWMurqmIOYAeplXCFFz78OOKFPfQwofIa270g4k83CXCjYsjPipaKhFBLmCWc0efL1zYDbSR@jySlSdiMYovd7BkGyYn6wiC/PIZF0IgCLQ4e9BOOSPHR5ELokiCzsGXQbx4zgiy3lAa0Cv90rohgSiW1EGAyQU/cd5LbE4lNTU/2APn7ZrVGyAChoEu7YYEo7xEvAnd9ZZgp8jyFrTMwTjQl@@ynPh9TYiTQO/KcXKTHELtyJqI5NQeuGsuE3G8W/J1lsYVN9Y1xDILtgsXhKcw9O6boDDtazatfgYlY8hT7C9Dkjs7mVDDJT8m61sJWfJmvnlTCiIimQ1i9drESbHvamRSch6xeCj61/psyg7olvQzATpTqNkYPlb0mx36mQOwJixnMCziUhBS5QVa/9G4Z4Kmr94SGNkACBlQSzOU9DE90BowrzyTdo2JwjTVzhCU4DRM0tD9BbBkqUiQnWZTewgU6IJFd59zwKxhcx7ZoLf2ZkxfbILwztBydLUtnv/xZ21ogNnm6SljUvw9RwPoRrzRebC1RFL00M/8liWYq6GuKUQGcn0JZUvB1QZF9xzzUaMGw5LJnmL1Ub8WjQvMiT/Qux7hM15yS9WHbdV9zs@ESDxpYOOpDa1PNYInThBpOvxA8inzIE9PUyzdVNqEhU@ENNVvbd4u6ohPCQKaNsiiryina8Vj/rKZ0xs6Q/6LK2VfaldtgN/5VFmbZLJMXmnKatq0laamPsIHlnI9bJvJwXWXKo1FKzzE7bwTodEp2dGVa@5soHM@AXgVLa3bVS33@RDYbQ90e5qUpG/p8QiruJoVI11ZeQynpfPfh0DcvSqe42E6aTr9fAtDEou0oNcgaXE5PBkgkzZFWF1pjnFy1vt2zsIMSWUFwVNpxeOZHI6x3tqHv/A@GDycHgdmSl8qzU/NF@I5SeZNWdJ8AT7JDVNUZ7Ek/4VeDyOX1lf0ZLYdcD4oxF2jp@@aA0oz9WRLV2xgJkc0h3oDzUc/jzE4DkYtZCvf9Qh7@8Vxl8AeWk3x0wxAE9E1e8B7nPA8JE2n7dA@GtwRQT9@UvTN0rdNyrDdS3qu@QLBbDm4ovEAv32FgOOLCbhcE2CglPkQ7VrmLX4fVDF65o3Kf@cPep/mluorRFVSJ87QWnOSt1tfYldcE6ef@VS8nlsqp6XPDReW@8npwNcytK3ppg3zcvx9jBCgYds2/53PykGaaYqRJANz0D0/mSjUgKWEQe2BllT0rqkXit20Aj8PNvfQ6qD4F8@vFXue2JLlL4stVzsyDVk8H5T312nr@kucQFZoC1erAs5HBtt5skuscjxcQZhD4BL0/MrtZIqUMpXmRpKHGsBq9W6Vsfv8CUPKQ9R1h5TBmHRrUP4wQakIDsfi@vZPyW3l8dzaXyeQZtCufqkSgca91lUQz/Q706Qsm5G/MYWcyXy9eOroQ3WoztXyDptXKm5C5OZc3Lmg6DpfBj3dO/zGQmVENZaEOTENxENjogf1Scwcv6rUOHij71EBo@gadPIvqjhz5d0AFPIBTraPwHGEjtmEXWM4mGjcAO2Oh8bx45TrDdyebbYnCokx3yqRil9WpCZ0dlul70P6/XbfhPmx2QeFwfiK9hdIyfLBfycQU4ivZkwYSOZm7y1pg0ILige0qHZtJ9E2/nVCJ/vQpJ6ASyWYthmqM8bfhyg9T4g2TVP/lpYBWdrWaLOxnsTtpV9qoRklR@xuYL75wkZTSLPzkOGCjzNihgnUw9m088j8OWiOemRKOGNaf2S0ChjavzTJhJGaLEO21XLdDzHkMXZqOVVMrT7KjlwHNZuqrvDHqLDyGL5SKvcoPk/rEMotLczgYg5fvvHXv8JTomcwBmJpbZig9NS@St5HNHulfTW03ceDQCMTv3OiU2lajHgg3UCDvm7g78RSUUAbckwDplSOYnVVnJPouIYpQh@Sr@4ax1zi7vWVrsrPIjwmOnzTBG574zM53znfSLHGd6K0IBlfqH@cFaDjXKtj233ORfhq3IL2HPYfxTavj7fQAvrFTp1Kz13a@YK6Z/TMntFTexZ1Ds/3UPcAjnT4KZLHKgHl7yn2Ne7zI3nkz@V6dpC6uqnrX0NdlIdcOprmfOPsNu7Rb0PSb8I7VpoQIR5ftOPBkE1EorH7ob7TU4cwMtmmYw7UJPkeAtXR4sN/59ub9w4jNjvXVKvNNymg@U9xtKauslsNinBlB1fG51uTmrqp4FbSR5R3oIz7/Br7VMu0vmj86CqmMxjQozHQhzb9kJ032ZlvwFxjO1TSr2EGzeH7QzjLql2z2eppXypSU1UcQ7tOu4Yc7n10XiqEMdVcY8ktDE7pGtDKGqeQCSrB@BN87D00/gWWcebWfnNoWeMvC4bJVX/P3spXCdDxUP5igXZONA35uAHK3ejzyFKFWM99kJtIgUZlOalmQCuRH7T/TOz1EtKLFhYfUHqm6k2FCaylfYv9UmwIIEueFtjUAOHzjBcPCcJdId9gVhjdHXbt2JcZt9cGnQp/5iKsdfFYFV9NsnXzNmBthq6vGOIxd1T2Vh4fWxjJP7oykkqL9c6kOnzQtqVrA5v/smQnOxfL7AL@LNR4/kxXNE9b7fDfL2l1fdPCze6gPiRblmq30OSNkpdLRC5uDLMLEjipMx/YhZ1b/Nn9AvP0ksnRLfn2QO0quPltX8N9cLo9O@AB5umtA1@D@PVQsbXXQ9NR5@Kc3kLwNShfKV2ttTvRAi5Cl7pipxR/THQADJptiNueZtOeY9cxv9NwFqPV@NnIaau6d/btcSNIQCcSWz9Zco@5W0Q9B9r1MV6Zm9ekxikW4h8UcppDxlLxnFvP@dstHrMg3A77g6EtHvNz7@MJgqDNuH9N4fatBhIw@REELuspujPfrhwwnIIuJUZB3/mQhv1e080ue1/MMFC9QLihwv0AY23AmHykONADDHuexkczoWwqj4dpvzTOTS9loqUiyVUc@yOwhppjSc3QnMetMo6jwKzIfWIVueKFZ2bS@/ibevatGJKn8@m0/1il@LaKYzrX550AsRNi4yKEaZY4fman3DOeYdrkSedB3PMBLIynVIY4fjmmlWIEF40q8XgsFuKJcAWgawCYC0Wn7PAEDj/AZzNdsx2C1Trs4oIt3Y3WMmvyPaswaU1i9TrHih86D7I9GtARuWOe/GJJqVeWIslkZClyaayxTMQDV3XoDXPBlQnYjkYPXl6fBMxQ@FZedLs1LvMTRnaPTu@B1tcG7fHMIKMOaqL8nAw/hHWKWw/@w1@1xaFGmGLaoHbBaAQEwTO9Zl/tmbdPeb4i99pgoOChSMQBwkvnR3SSmzUGvQrUTH6W0bxlZzunRXFCShwgBs8RV0O8UvDGRUMH7m92eOPx0nh7VUXGXiq3Ui1TH/YNUOzbTs9OsRONti4PLX8PIrgQzHAsnN20E2yPtVVc4KUd6TSh103zmo6WYEn@w1/xc2G0L13sF3azp/OggRxx@7lMh7FaLXMIpXaRfFItU4BEkcggyoZoKgPmVnl4DHdr04E14Mike1yLsuFntjZrJyy5zSJ4NhpPgZS1TnSpdvz8zUWmXvmB9dPqf/xZOnYnCCd9lywVbCnBXJDyPTJWMDoP0X5shElLI4ln6G3a18Sm/VveHkAihTMZ7tt3ecw0B6LX0JFbOmHqcaO4@iGKbmpn99xWn07rEsOqt3RuizbLGiji8RisYUMHA2@MUPNeV1mKDrlFJ3nisDxkiGffFHDx8720jR3PIGGSpRH7zHrIZMkWbq0GHyekjsfe@pUNd8dPLrgvK72lNoe0GeEmm8rmKlSdpUZlvUouS22bePz04vvLUTaTvBytbtfTtkvUy8vRd5nsW6C6CZPNpSdp7HnbB1t3S6lq5vNnWxkzSbqPlPk@MhATS3dHe0fbJ6e107MTaIV7V/zsmFZf8WUNchFtlu6ZOh3sBbpYmmp/g/zxfAAejbIlha3jlRWxWCi4D5hABa2lpLTEnQHRNJH6C8nnpbfVQPwsgJBpHY25HLUHwwC2ITAbUg0rPxzg8WQm0oojlsRlGsp47EAeYXC33hxZSqSSWAWIlQRifSWp2MOVfcrDvoZiX8TyONmezgVBinn5XXjxvIpzSXD/O6n3AAbK377eHMvj9SaYR@oNoF6om2antrd/drw9mQx4jJ4kdSulvNgAz4Uz9jRuDHLPlNJZIZEQrWEViUmUgHvFYEb3kTRV51aFagnh2OrzxMShVH4p5DMmUKaCl7rUy5wW0SiVAHWQMlZran9@RxsFiuiO0QF0d7yKnhDYkTzUbsFTksAcpgs2Uvhxq4FYBbncrndEQlzI64gdVH8Sbo/DquEYDco2pXpgqPJGHZvBf2BUcl3ZOhsxMZzJdZZkWfjqKkw0ex5srMzHKLbECSEt8bJLXnnxcgcoU/tKoYkp7RUTRxBglNaVAZ4kF9AHMBlcYx@HJp13coWJp1/c4rRH4feYUNO2FKwNnaMyHDwV7o5bhG9v56SC2hlXzUi@B3luaOBABUCBW0W2RzCjAWbrkKzn9xNwkpviKLw7VJKV0hZHXz0twWY3mk1WTGyEDuo4OkhKrI2oOF7pQyfdWE23QSdpw/DNL8Ah5SRF@5n5puakwaQw8GTKUxkTTAohrF2ZPRoNQ@ltC4bVDzzxEsERZjuAM7K@mEwC5bqa4V5Bs4bGVrJCrTHHGuKWgGpkJolbhDVyJXtOXw8Azrkk4lJN//hP/5xfDHHpgPsXwj3KbIDvj4SvA@5/4sbIMvj@mefLgu@Pue/7NDbZ7Gl4kb2whj64@Rv48pk0UyeUCe49PFQXr7Wxpd/sHTGbLMLYln1lFGgmlDDIc5oB9NL6wBQ31MYIznPwm9DHE714AywCfAX8geoNajSUn2rVo3gmei2dxoLj1DVFe4jVETcH0xHpj0O8GgSUsHQhX1iR01DI5I2LkM4pdnHTKkcYi62BTAzdaIPKh2YLjyIwyW4puloplDlvpJeU73PSB6@gSwAb4hOFCwZp8PSClwLiqiJZdEmJyzFMigNZRI6gTGubnNVAG4ySA0BiGGy4B71A3TQFqYCPDXXkkMY0didATbwCCk1ZKr8gxkWUBEQcN15gMd0d/W2ouGs/0EFTwWaQzhHsBMHWpHnMevE9u3Qujbq4yIQB4/1qDusa4P7Hc2434ZyFJzdnr9WITl@KgbVhz04ME7cr70BpWTSbzubSciEW4FBJoILyYlf/DCihc4OwaKnalTmwa5vbey8Oj05mrocgyMg0WIRFquvxy2QqcVH3HBGv3JNE3dhJn7za2HFJGSyVv5iPEP6K/nQx5@U2XdIHcj/n@39n86aImYzkzNcipuWz5A5teJnF7semA4CbfN/hTK7R2N39RX29emmEZ7L/PO/KnHBqGZkLXJc2XZgTmS4mFnHP3dV8ilfx2Sn3dEtW8i@E8s7kcL8f/PAFD97Ffv4tD@7@6RCdv/SOX4ZSD@yshrqn0jwruuKAF8wtL8gat6gyFtXPsBWa2ZARLA0TdZm9g1AcMPKIdMhtSO4NcjaHtEk4cysTXbXi0cyDO3UxYtf3710QFw70oHS61gzdirOx7vEs71xsyh7omhONhQwBMX1QaxbSfvT6Ag9MqVyMmHfiyEadcZQiA16Ubge6rYf47Q/MvaQhTvc8HA2BbkfmgPlWtC3VdR2DTsW2hpBFCydkL4Z9gOvQ41jF0UIFLSsJiYGeEbcoF3izgaBEqt/OR0exVE8dtbUujDjRWAJE03ey7N8QoeAVB6BXNefVAM1Sg54CdcCmya3jBQuj2HqJvH4FuT2R3c4PNuohQIZJm7E1brmInBnuZT7Y8GsskvAo04wlIinGZ1Linh5aVCZDVIpt9nALHpk@Oh2NVLbguWs@mHc0q5/CWsEww1noOW7ADXLNN13WEaCMcqGkNKOtjqJ4LnqtjnSC8Mjt@U0kJs2wON0YIu6HaE9fHeLKQsURQsm/dmNK3pVKnpybFA2lUqpnh/DsGkxKIMcTx9oHJ6gI0U5fGbDokO5esVmKkTd6GTUStmPFWLKKw/UtM1g8TjYNeFAEzFkQtEMujQ65R/Gqsmi6Ao2EobbRxscnbcAu5FSqDm7KJMaW0J65CdoUWgJjIZijQpI1Qgv6BfytYYn4xZIpccHkEmUbousPAGpuNMmpbo/kC9CCas2qT/yz5gEBw6laKq2J1piU9iUGfLE@RyAC2jlS3J0jAH3F6SOgGspogNq01LYG8vLZS9UwVCAQ8Ewf79FUhsBkVizhXvGa8K9goxzCvIi74jgTFHTyarbtyJ1ugrq2lC6Taax8D2rNh0vUazpCsxmn/9t0Kl2@iy7plXEadM1YNbrUq8jx3HI8vmQsR5cM1LaePEGL2v0SKHONFExQRwCUXNJjZeBnUP4qS0Z5SVmPLrUr2WVKAV6YIt9Bgh/sdOpuSblPLz0BZSkBIRYXOtElm25NyaRS8j2UD3vIUjoBPHOH13/Qxa2Y/ZIWj2MZUksNLMAP6cuTOA2blydpMt6VxVwg3e2L7jalinktMXPhLCegCF7zBqw8DlhiV1rDBfYvZsvNi3tA/eMZv8S9u4y2HKh2cPIlTcZ8vWARchplrhAyUX5tDRBwFAUiojehxGIgTH7zm7BcYEx6WshFzfjTfKYcj@RlmKbD/Dr8DPTw9LJkSXeXW8kbpiYjFx0ln/pYP7o@Onobu4yyEouENw8leUX6npWy7Os@qyz7wIf9Np9weDkdCqeX5Ser6fSHDx9gxgGfi2qqCuKDf2IXyUj9IrrKWHV1dTlRKC4nnkUagYLFotls7ISl2aWmaQO73Yav2aNblqNh/nn6lPKC6T/8Mx4m8hcO14MgIjT8rXBKPswuVxVlOb6SfWaUoWgl/OSYDE78LcJXZvk828bP3/7vf/tnf/sn9Pdn9P33Crtmn@Bz3WH4T@5P7YBbQXez8wlvlYGpRYXkwiASyeciJ99H2H@2zyKTq09X/9OfHH4MO@FqNn1uwdMJfwwXimHuBAf4cq7vJlwNryNY4T48TlcqFXCu/qf/FdJXXwAejBmvw0817@IqjMPVZIWSfA5XC@CQs1nI9//@2c9C4eoo/Cksy3J4TH@NcEbGT/GJ/IQxcKSl1aJkms/c8o4CHzcsLcvZS789A82NTesF9yAfaFdmhidBye1xFRPcQI5vgcN7hAuLzz5sMabCUIuftbVnMwTfn/Ifp5LwSYluMEJPcuRWIVysJBo8e49XwwHHVIW9Xybq7vm/ES4Udi/DTF4onfoE1S/DcnHl8Nnoqz/ML7RLxLBPOy9zNh3mUt3zMLfTs2@BC4V/qFSOHfx71cS/oxP8Y6Of8gHUT@GzCH/0Dx/Pi7@LFCKCCWT2s/hbdNdQ@CJ8Ua@/7tGfhX@7Bv41P@Lf/if8e@3g32kL/45f49/pe/xjM5UJhdfX18Px@DGohoJnv@ZzBt9UqiF8Lu8iut/ph60cFg6fhVg4WY8n7@8vUt@P4uWy@Aelqez58MNdUKz6fTK5/n01Hr@g4l1URTnXk/UqlJUXmX6@XwfE8fWL9fVUo1qtJuvfVy/WJxOJdM@exbGfPoOE1frFRSh8h21RwZ9l/GnZ@JuVpDR5cbCA0bkELkZOeogARvfgoz8U/rD@IRp/Gn@a0TM3Gflavn5lHvr/h4cjiNBGmSvTyvQyPbkNEpFl1LPMODMeZfrmodwGpwp/mT44tUxnlOlmjIwhy@PRBKqH//uHpvPq0ARsJqR0RhkHEWc68OweHr4CfB3I@wr@tEwmM4JCjjI38J/RUVDTFVv0/L4RuwxdMOmDCqN/So6kMpFUIRLR6vnC4OPl3X228FFKRBqXF5F6OZy2Ly/TXDti2ZUyXbB2f99obB9sNRpp5KP1pfizePIZfCrV@Lp4PA1Xy08v15LYfpz/Uo1wev3pZTWXRHchDo2UhbD1dPwbPz5KeFYXL0Mw4Ts/x@/57c0td5GDXJfn514s/qQxiFwUBB8ATc9NP@FgoGn@nv7bh/9l/b86Y9GLeoyx6N39epQ@MfyLxe7u7@7FbzUWjQpPdB3@MAD8mOTuvopOAroD10U0Vo/d3/Mw@I3G1jnCKuaxXqXEPiB02DDP9TJSBg2vshQVi2qXl6NMJlZuQohnXlc@0/pMrEw7V5aauKYGswF5OUYg@ZVyeUW4V4vlclG45UKhXF72oDLgEU4AUm2lVUZGL4djWATO/dEM2lToEstItK128Dbzp4MBTOzkUubzZy@o0WhrVqOB4bnPny@hI0Vw30qllIeQTPHzZ@iDkRhM@g5MsWJagimcnM6iUwZnfn29sFKtFlbAXSjGYmXpYumOFyLajZfkGLtfStdVW@JlhMlWJMx3u0Tl4mqMQu8jS2mpzMLr7GkV2NeGD7u7DxMl2Uo@Fm2O1RhbKUSL8ZL4qyzG2Hq6uszE38VFLr6yvLr8rF73RyLs8OU7pSLfV@6UNZzu35db4jZI3PenPHmSK0EVi5nyZajR2Kqd1hp4rb4koTQdMIahJDtCuE44sCIXZJzJl@oXWO76ZSSyVn7G26iYZ@FIWcAlIyCFWLFE1QvDDFDr4I7fEQpp8V2Tl7O5xXR@9F1hOwMa8@dl/FxcXBSzxfgySKnlUqler1Po50VKc9Efdep04VAleSEX8vUkqiJXo84yFFZezYWXQwPaFbSaYW1cWLXQ2LUIgT3FZk1cA7dVXXdv4Lw1Lb19q7VVwH60X9vcPk1k1wFldqe2mcienG2EZfTmfT9F59B/vF3bOjyDBEf727WT7ed7b7bPjiDchgEPiAWf/pGiDtWGejsc3qK/odJnU7OVqytlMGgM4DPq/Pirn//4q//ux7/44x//4uc//sWf/fqXf/Zz@P4VfP@YP//435by@PvrX/6z//nHf/0XEPjv4fvv4Pt//PqX/@Jn/Ev@v4Hv/xkI@xvxDcDxL5ASsP3Rr3/5J3/561/@k38J338lvv9y@vvjn/5v/P//En/o/Isf//Rv8Ed4fv7HP/7hn/z4h3/w4x/@4sc//IeA/O//@lf4/yd//ff/7lf4/7/8m7//6//h7//ofyLHn3PH//Ov/i3//bs/@Pnf/eE//7s/@OUDvz9/9PeXXxH@y99DyNeX82vwfE29vjXklz@pPL8NNfxciMH@7B//@C/@EXDun3Lffw8@@PeifuF5vJg4TdOScT/wF4x9ToMilHn22QMFlP8jhkIw@zyJjUIzbuivf/nP/xKDJ2D/URBDRp6FXUJgL7dfAOy/9goWhP3Fj7/62Y9/@Q9//NWf//irP0KBllwpJWqJpPwFgw4A5r8CDgELXwMHgPI6rm0vssVQFhyL62iACMnxDx@ApIvgAoV6OZTPgS8kV8ktoxsSwvxkmc@Q4zjvh@8otFICH5oE4jCExHlUHKI24qxSqcRDowrEESh4Mc2IVYs4CcI5QAXwYiKeJtEogn7JRhuEBVJW4sessVwZ8YRxDKgSBoYFwqBjSc5K8WJlCzKsjLYY4kLk8dAHeH6oVIuVURXR/UBFABzxDcgSoCpYulH1B/BXCCfAh0ZbP0BRipV4vFqEkApVlXJLNChPOU@Vo7rHGdUbwxlDi9jTZ4x9J8lFic/FgJRMQONv3Id@ShaJpxB/GV8W1aF/10nfZUwP7TQi@vAwHv8Ugym9AAC8ySTug4JvMomleQbRI44qTtnCI84xAOXiwnTjBdAoGw/FqX3j5IH8oQxf91mvBjyIDquztLQErvWqlJMOQaln1vWa7SgWLhOQRrPGpEJJwmDcVqIuHZHav7y1DL8y/G8v0tZQTo7l0FIEh/IIc/NIxnPmihmm0rtVo7osU8njBBcK@@Fc1aS1HtARV1gsFKUrpWM0d1QHoMGEXtndDXME@mBCkhJyocRNpmJq@c5cW6v8IK@shuBJ/iHeZi3uVYZmwDccpbB3IUGrd8l16mngBHWjEKpWxXoVk0PVk@1TSHB6yORsJsVAibxbWc2u5Ffy2VyhkF/NyiuF0kohX8yBhCpk8tmsXFpZKRVLq/dQoGfQzxNry838evUfzHz@m38w7zM/FD@h6ls2SrGjo9fJ@1B1lEyms1TkipxfLY8rUBAKClVJk@L68vguCUonNk/okrZG3eEuHCha6C6JrLoAHxZaCLEFCIIPYEZrPRNLyHuHZbGWhu8K4OtpkpwHZoiFLoEZOLbQIPAJYbs9AWHzRObOfMF3ZtB5iidiDgA9tILB9nHLomOyU5NvjdtQW6F1cXKjGgrRusMF0LQewnu4L@qh9bQXOx/TZo@/PWvTMkFD/ekwG4pxzaO2NLyBr@V4UbsKXrFj9zWn9wDE2aCPR0pU6/eGYbvfhAKi2ZEDbMCPpZvmPIBVdnb0QC1feSfscAGPjtgB@PHe893TwPN0u7a5GyqwjcODralHXgDl2f72zqnnXeWxbtK8h@Ld9v7@tFc8cJaxyPKriQSIR/jBZ4I@9Ewtfe@CyKmHx001lUnIMAw0xupdMnnfVPGm9RN@l/yoo5u2HIl01T6Mc9CTZXw/V9fUYTa1lNnM4AJD@jPOhhpqNj9mSyATSzAtZOv5aiEs5aVipZDJwrhD99t3jHK4ABPEi1K9MmI5VryoD8L2SrmUk@PHA9W0o/JqbDVTyrcs1axsDIuOE3qF28BKMj/OoNmhXZjX9PHSbzws7oQstQ1znFuDTmo08QU7wwF7MBAeGIROS@v2QGDemh4ATDdDTUVh8P3WD@BQgx/n8QCH50FhMzH6LHjo1rMWeWYg5tmDhBw5x73EdI7IXXSmQcleC52i@Kb3LjE8BtfEVxXQ0S3QC/hZXHqxgArCvBQK4UKb1mGZUIrMZ9lSMV8s5bLFRLFUXMnDdDOfkLMJebW4WgK@ychFuVDMl@REcaWUWwFRDrH50mooDOJO66TTMFLJkkRPzWjh1aDreMeqmepVQ2FufgD1AN9UF1a8gGGRSbniZQbSSXhLu@3QxtplmJXjCyEz@LpFWQpJCmux8M7OZmZnR5I20IMGw82MJLXRky9mMqsbkqRSzCaMOVlJMnkaiAIwh3symY1NSRpyBHiiEXD30LddQO1YkjT0bNZ2djCjK/RkEQFguOYx3KO7nlUAM9CTy5F6LUkfPXSIvMazWqGybqMHc0UUOzxmE@Ik6blbokwGUBxzOIFi161urSZJe9xTqyGKF1T3PC/sS/TU6AOJLPAB90tSFxxdS1UNSWqCE/uAJLXA1RorENYHFx6CNBxFksacSEgmSRoRtNK6lkAbFOGQD5Rnd1fpOW21yz9jiz9bELUHUdpouL3TfP682e02rXFt@/kxRb14satcjYdWs9sUCZsN@JiYCqKu@@Ppj4pRjYaiz496CVHGVFRj3FCphA3lI5RMfLqYUb/xAqNeQNS8FRmBED59AG7iZ6MPzw2lyaPcD0XRc9RsSmXk2xD2n1HZGQ9UNPqgr6@0LLNMv6wfjd1lyvcY3InSmx1QisfuUJhGF/tPJbmUl9YWFXBkV6Q1FMpmJ8IiSfnpsCgVVqW1ZXhKT6UcOEfRTCTDGPzELlbrT6VVSCo9fZqULmT0lcC3uirFeHaookDmnegoMarIEJhOr2Ovx34KT9CIhDpzqo6c1K6Ke0BayeT5xGd9/Rzg8BQoHuE7GPbZBrslQYMb@t09zY3KBkiVTNnAo@MqepdG4VGo2lYcBSY2G3fDtTUBe1/uVi4QwWf8WU9K59Vzqc6C@eZXM1CqM6OVXV1fv/hcB62uIpfHYRiMssXyKExnNlZXylGYRMQqtvqR63afdbTGLTYqGa7lLdnD/kVmsSAn7pKN5L2u2M6SvJpduxguXSTl@uJi5nN3XXpfleqYPSp/9Bc0GYL4K0OYSzIuMMMd7QPEs7Ukf92FXCzEUri1vGF2GnSlPfsQkIt@wkEZxmldBWVFLmXLAiQ0qPA2j0osiu@q4XtcopHIajYSiUXKALUIwaI1iW0i0OSRJzKwDAitNamUhXhLdYagvwCrucX0SsB13oIcCt@H2niR6UopFL4L3d/dr1dd9eAlG4@VeNL1PmGsG4fpT5pWNHAtZJFcyVT1GatVat3jWlmA1jZpkgIMdclPTiXTi9@6bhJfr37Pn5e4ZgbZhDhxaGkxvR6vpqvV6mVIkqSw5Fq9o8U8zGxw@v9DmK6hY5t3naFBx9PXXiG5lDWu31zUYz8caPpdMZeskuYchd5wH46vp3E9LlVNE7Fah7RaHQobpnCi3dSBzhEF5T4v4TRKZYOT0ver3xe/f3V2eHa4w55l1oprRU4J2j7wLJGQI3IEKPsMRkjteDsUHnw28/IPxotyeG0Qya1EchOK2WVFnBuOIh9EL3CVAL71C5gi1WPgqlSyT@VCdg2UpnAVTy9mV8NVcsiF1XA9zBOvQGydbxnLyuFqWgTLq3IsbCe5D/g5H7ah8YuvPnyGqa14i6aWJVc6LUq0dL9@D//V@wuY/d3TJPCe/vEnDT/3HAD@Edzz8If/CcAFYfz4@g/Jdf6/Tj@bh7zQUgGoHf5QqUKjft/4vhEOhUuRajwdwTdCiz0OYl6FitOyQX@qvYx/3/sBy6DrLXs@8K4vs3xVZkxdTqfTl7HXWdB7SqVCsRAO/Wb2k16GGeDyQo1F@G0uXN@iV6O7h2MiE6/jwon78kJy6@Rw8yXMj0HhUg18LSHbPDxIYRS@Oc8/3dTSVcXSx@LVeWOEQj3tdPMIX659tnVEac7pXBuF0vxc5LK0114Tb65I3DA5lWPZTCafzqyk5TyTi2uZ1bVsgSkgbmw8xy5cS5iUUbU2zcGYa8fRzRglXqghDMbtazDhsdU19vxon1LQEfflha3tV4fs8GD/XcoN5eGnu3sn7ORw5/S8drwN9Xi1fcKk2gnbO5HY@d7p7uHZKasdvGMQfVw7ON3bPkEE6RCKKhw0OcE81ZGt22M7jSOqTfrjRLBttq5VZzJcsQZKGi8nnAw28HUFKt7yPRk@NGDW2A6qpie1BZhHDlv4QuHWtdJuWyE8UKe12AJqpAvLqoW7TqVexl5l@eHbTxkrv8haKweRVdbKHBi59VWmZ8Qf01f6uWO2uLh4aUienA9Ww9OMg0G4FRvC/DLtvd9eiBZW2DKowtmVmB9zcHi0kHF9C@fHpwuyF3e8tZD1PHs7CznPsw2@Fc@3c761kPd8G7WXCwU/2cHmwqrn29reXCh6PmDShZKP82BrQc6EXGLdmFp7gV7JFN3Z299mywAUK0/EosUEHVPBQIjo0LD57QZIcra8fNszE6RPNcdT0G31S9Au@ATUAuojF0jXeoItmwP46av9MqlwtDuaK2hWt5UQWPHqDhg9QnehBazQAlYI4BfwXC3CscUKy8YYRC90@EpwlF/slGDSmU2n576z2TpqBVVghgTdBUKnKCGFKt6gFlq4FyijHbIqdWhrKIHKUFLJkmIxPHp1cLa/zzMbQBamFZUIkpFHmoPTHAA2qCL8YtUhlDcObxZqC6TVglAe8C1vofuJ1gxNtyaSAuq5sNACBJPUvVH0BEM1K4HLkogXPXxLNwBDNLgz4OJnzqLRFta1qzotKlAMibl9uMNriAubFTbZyjGGmRKlKJpvFv/8mbm@S2fSa016jQjHLZDzYnF8vKQVhI1h2IJ72I8g6GAzpVxAjonHITVUh@IC9VoAosOXn4N2S1mFjDIR9uQJlWMdfKUIZYHp4pQjSyIIIhAEI/IhMq9oi1Tc2EJ6GbcQ8FckIxFxHOF3BTbH3h0OIFmnCzrVql4v9JpzwVBtpzwlkEVUp41tDe5ctgF@FI/AyQnWhG6SYG6kXMBInFEkmJpgHQiekqkNzQDOVS1fJrqsAJ2RWv9gi7cQv7CEwnkA1Rjk3ho1GAiLJ9h9idEXFpqWqlyXXSiQhwQFfItME0VCcLjH0x1vUbJl3l@QLTH116Tc21lz@YinBnYQnEZkxfkK5xVRXQqs@kAz@AUy7L8VQM9ZkiOLxwWEx2UCbHsSLpnkcPcuX36hEtvTtVj85lqgWH6wFttfWY3frhYwrPksArUAER8FvHGApp/J1szOQwFjIaGg2vw0FDCA@rwEfXwCwVekhyHXT5/89vQwSK9Nd2Xot9CCXCrwJJPe1qS3PenF7gshCoMpQXaFfWZNdMkFcOFZY1YER5vLysmEnUkvGRwqTHXTdDwJzHMAnkNRycGQAWeFMUqQlI33mit9fLdGhdV2GnsH26eTsYgvZTdEwXv4emnKIzYJJgqE8XYUPTGvRNEOEoHrm9EjnkeC6Nk4OT3err1KQPlibN3vAdM6APyInjBRg3s3Bwg11BaMx@0Ei57U2HKMPcGSJZiwCaDnq7PQTVsFVA/m2B4OspRVhoN4/smeFMYeGZqTlRRl0Rj7fHkJQ2pmlcn9wedcP2es5tpsnFtFZZfj8XQQIeVdAXPAuyZXNhAS2FPB2zLmZnaVybAVK8cctQca9yhjzeKnet3j2EbDonsicmDSpMwu0xvKUbaI@yNgXJxUbR7XImlsRD7AUOzGEIbDOVm14qSfI3tSrKtg8bK01W8ty5c02smyJHlZ1inT2TL8Rhj2YLoUmjr1StdwmANnoODBUBF5OECbyREGWaEQt6UEbmOKmvhGAye2RrdooExpNPC@ukYjaqt6B19zPLRaMOSjumwLMPxgbIpHUkdCx2SkIA/qT5MRbQ0PcuJFgzDqTCGkty1X6O63KOUYCnklsx11QKUKFAPNYfi6z2CG@Mb6oB@aFQ9YBUocWxNa8Y6C/cFFdjFxgQ7HMbR7iTnBIJ5nQz02nRPnsc2cOLwnbV4S9@DvnLirYX9eCUAwPBAjju7NiTHMw3kJ@P0zfkT9IkDAiyCB6/VobH7TQ7@abPHABUJE/1NrqIrbcPYOAywIyqXgwEBbh7dUYNqWhvdETyPyDg9DyugoFjjH7LFVzOckxW5p2jR6F5NARAfx6CpkNlrDF8aPvpOzxVgigDCAES@46yv6QzhZACmUcA6SMH@zN3OtnLaHGllwGq@fPoXH8I02TO/8BObgEXiM9WGx8V3gBbxByYvxmHlOl/PRrc0yDoWjFR6bX564a@ohaLcScixI0N82@@S3Zp8M5I998idlXWEXk@WoxwP@NQjw6@h28J@UkVvqydxi31TjINeo6vUD7It3ggSy4XcBTGbroRESyOMptyqEHgO@UkggriCib5Av1HzipPK81P74s1xhSdlLwyWe3xvIrB4ofAhvMWg08PrPRoPufWs00LLUaEg8Bxp4ccALDrqis/G4FGipDZNio1JSkRJSMlk72dzbS2qGlODX71Yk2zEttYHXN0mJNkyUKhIJrAbC9FR9UJHEZi3FZpRaejiPWiAPqOCXMyEgngu9jT14r@eXs2sFq2R@RZXMqcz8uwa/Irdjyg2PVT@Wk8Uv7XIz2qR7pfCiLkvVUNDwi4XFu3LxAoaJc/9o0hdF4PnaZOmz8bYFXiR6NDBMtDVeW0BvJK4wsvZJ7j0k0sy1IaK3o6kHEficyrlPOqJXjzC6k6qtCj2LzEMpyb@PUBQsJWoa4HdXQePXOPgD2uTdJKK8Cdc2aaMZc6qovmAxB1j5CwmvLoEGODIH8OtdXwJu7wITcOMVJhjkijpw4/0lmKIjHOIqE3DRZSbwBPaW/LsT@8pI6w/RcBM8IC80Ob9YOORjTWjUp8hJ6ccpihApHS@hjQq8sbi0JkHVbbo4ZfryFISfd39KrB6aFbJ02y8WM6A6zEM690aWWOJ30EgBRQxFsy1KA2kTEpO4EkJp5bU6TD4DvOOKGFSfp8JMbvVERFCThJfeH68C969UJqYXSBGYPPDC@Am4lSn4ii9S7mNrngrit1gQiituc8qNmy0fLHgQg6uoxUKPzKT@fzNPCjbJf6FTpf/vJ0UzU5/f81TmkSnMN89WfofTgv@q0P9Xhf4nKPS/M23@AZV8GuVsj59S17@ohn@7@kUybwzDhtW9QdNb9qfoYb8jRWD1m/QAt9QX8mO6wJfHZxdNNjis/8RROvSb9Gm7cL5j1mq1075sHT@vdWu92vE78G9k9uPnVysbW7cbzzfata2t7ovu5oH6ulhb2R@8fFt897zz6aMK2vvu4Yv3n/RBqxd6ezy4PVePbnNq0a4Nhx/3dsfO7sZZf/Mk/271NrOt5zsb6sct3d56dfr25enz/En89uOLoxef@pm@fdTJKKV@bvdV4c3m@NwI5W@0s/bOvnbYP2lvn2X7@1vau534Zmb/pPRazuxv377Pbd7G85n03uDl4fPjs6vm9nv9eG//XXvzo6kUPl7fDvbS7VJn8@r4Tegw91re/Xh42N3Olp7vpm@3OoN2JrurW/mrt8dHG2fvdnsvle3@Tv6s9PZqfFTovX594xzEuyvnheEreyVu1F6/zr40nt/cbB@Hmop5auXUc/O1PLi9PTJL/VX15cFut//ako30Yf5N/KR/eru1vaF/XB3lzt6dv75dOXk3fPX6xfvDjHZy0txWCoNmO3tydboSavVze/Gbs@2zovK8ff66f7O3m3@3lX7VUw9q7SP9@nl39715crS/V8vZQ0Pe37zR3z3vXb263trc082ja92oraTz@mn73eFh6OyF1txSd9/aL2pXvXfp/Mb1yrt4e/D89OpT7/rFxsnZYTE7OhpnzE37uLnbGW0dF7LFdEv/ePypY76Sz17HCzdXL7Lau9onJ5T7NM6X9vV3at94EW91348@6un4mSxvvt/79O7dye6N1awZZx/f7BxfWa/axqF9mDl@8fJVU78uOleD98bJidzKPFevX8UzSmh0tmtDG6mnSn71tL//ejDaMj8e7723C5/iN@fXOXXr@vhN7eNxpnlrDN4a1r7W38y0D5XaG9PZHo6et0o3Z9e7@v7HQ/td6NW2nM/vmB17o/NmpfQ2/TzeuX7@dkM@GWUOjOPOSsE6ePP6XNO2e2/PPh238jtvBsW@Y3Rffzrrb8e390e9T2ox09RP3l0bobP8yfFR9tZ4qfWdnd3jVwXnMLP/5qi9O5Zrr1X51ljdHOe3RlYhd7711np3vWsM0u@0j8OjjHoTb78bOCuvtWan9UZr9V@GTl70zg6O3tzu5QvW876hbRwVMwf7u5sH3fbKy/Heq@H2fvOq/Xzvrfp2cFq4zm5vnBe23p7knNPrl06pddPPHRXjp3rf6Z7FQy@GveHq0bn18c3o/Uqt31Rzx/o7c7wq9zdfDLKjN7Xtw0/d66OBeSDvZMfps33zWs98Or39tGsXauN4cXTm9E3nVB7l5deh3O2ngfNi8OL1yeHGi8P3L5QVTTtXrk7etDO5s2Ja61m5vULhuby90@l/7JdU@dPWq5yS6/fi9v51ur3ZPntzfq1f9V/2r1qhYslubey9HyrmdjMrZ95tdLbz6v7G/qmsnnVfnqxsHWSO3raPzj6OTtubb4dnbw61zPbVi9J@d@Xt8ZvSy9X3p/apcm6@fWkdhEbFnGnLhVL@NndSKh72rJPc@VXJef/yqrChnzflF3vZvrqjWW@L4@L14FPvtnt7omaa3edbH5XjzjZI0rOjjJIfXh@MTkK5N6f9m9XBRvzddevlW0PWi@faavr041Xputd7ebvVWjmvffqo5J9fqaWTnXRT38k/jx9vvj666m6dfyqutDMb@2@Ut6PtnvMu9HpX27oqnV8fjsby652Tcb@WMfT8zcl5/ubU3Dg53z0p9l41rU5z96oHsqE/Pru6Hd7sqqu90W3xZe/qjZLZf1vcNOyVo0zohbrXbx@fvnxbi3eyasm5OXx3MDgvno/yr4rmeck8LGova53no9eHne3M6kA7Px2dbffSG5tavwgy5Ug/szYPX@@@P38xyISyRmHj06aZX/0Yvxm9K5ynj@L7w3et02z/3LJ232rWztubo7cvT2p78b3m@PnRtXL4bjt/crC5ab@I72gFdbybu7Vrmzm9Y4bs/sboYGQNSrn31/tdGAnMdqn9/DR3bti1Wud2r3iyXas9t5t7L5TR6HlnFcYI/GyfvzErod/wu9FC/Fo0/lD41Quhvt1tmiOQl/zwV4gO4oToIE6IH72hndB8l/Fv0suh0@CJGnpBJTfwDJugrLG2icpDiu15d43iqwYSrG9Ccg1dLXNAT0TrWFpz6KDPNnX4JXsVHi@jV2ypo4FuavgWF7xRHueklsrPsIH6kgodGqw/xvmmo/b5OR8NX8QirgalS@j5@27oasLQQqvF3BeRpejiS@@1ZB9AgRgY3STddNplyWSroytdGxx6m1wfQifeTdyYg64paPzALOT9hiJn8mJrKqqrVLhTfH/MwXOmm/yKe3fGoYAyMaZrJ9BIRVdPqPgOU1u7UfUxvbNAbadCfMfnV@2CDIbhFu7JMLqecWpvKKgbqjW1AXTAE7orrenlZ3gtyLPltFhiRWWooVhNzcHXYDb4qw4aPEd3z9tgcu8hHfkUC7RcMULNhi42TYjDHyP0TaVCitFWcv@YE@6ngxxBRXV3Gy4vDwgl7bti3BPAvDx4GLfW7/6uUE/gbmvqBF4TaDUEWtGC9Mya/Xc2bXL0gMohvli//XbvtCFebMG3GHoHVB7ZcRmgctn1Dcq8BoHyi5LPbsvEHQZQfDQ78nuBoao3JudlifY94vZIaG2cYfu7Lek1z1h0xDag3SgXK3W@gzBDW/dcgntpnnBOeBIo1ROfoAtiQ4XHA1@Zjm/Q5CCz9UXEHUtVCYB2c7onQKY2@/2Oee@BlmnqinGNrjLfKgvzBasVaCy6sj9QDzRleXUR@ydpjoD1hqTeNli/oJLlNQsBiA2xbjOfGdidab89puEt7GWN9jHMw5t16brZivrRy@6WG163mJsTh5/K6hAtiR3cWWtaY54Rmmei5TKA4D4dkgmq4e5WDdS64lMD0dGmnkApgG/LbhCeL1f9cibY46XlWS0SO9AOoPlF5ZuBEOrCK1adZ/WwLAR6x4KVmUjqE8fdQgTO9DJzzAEQoSM4DoYx4hG@O3WGKnynl8dFjNPpIlOHf/Y06FnjG3exQ6lo9kQREsNujDP0qcJ5hUbQqtd1MCuf9aihcAc3NqFGvMg0mOFjONPi8Yl2CiC/0JBuMosTtaNzYkEMeTUSpBe0JxjaEwetwbfisg7fwcVpHZoi0Tpk9Pmz12HA63HjkXsQGFjCe@kuMjjnTN6XBUHLrt/thJ6bYnyieFL1fnYvPXJ3Fybg5u1AG6l6FARmA1/YMWAQJLYsDQbcQRDe9iUIxsamsgt5tbgYhVQXBJcu1tkTFpXX16OrySgFfVeMxbzOKJJnA8kDiUFIV6ssml2O5tzEK5gYUOYmEazMR5DlCFaWo7KLICsQyHnAwFUMQvIdK3KunURcDCD28NYnYfC1H3NyX87G5fr6ehH3eAYCpxJn5xd9ORfPQmKOeiE@GcPR8ohAeH2yRoA8lw2MIwEUK/EcoOBZxycj/FynIrxMg3mu1OcOTr8z5cU9p@EOPpQc3z6oWhdFrC9yKt@UPmDgHjiWCMQ3QA3oPVB@GGfpZWRz0BGoS0JuPRUPTSX4e8DEoAX0K0@NioHDEQSBYoCI4OLREuzqsbGu@e2DHQJ3yMDH65xgcoIVYRoCEgUkRhESgwghGmjdRqs/8OBgKC7G@I5vPoBRJge44oznB6CdUO13cyIxxsmHK9yAT7yHicYQTt8oJGjs723g4832Me6Y3Tt4Dk24gPVIMP/XreYix@hVcVMx@LshNEeDIoBs4xMaUVfeVJP5Y6Cbv8DmIhfw09h5QqodQjCeWGiHxBea09BMgY2T0uUj1SE60quKPIBirAzzDHarMkVHcoz5K1aL/I1GdOiNUhOpwOElFAVECiHNTo9rByc7h8eviHJHjdr@0W4NMcMEs6VYbUbv3MAOYhiqzgdVj54hHH5BQvM6KU33BRH0xmOC5S9v48QDwAbFNCh0ukRYX870M/A8eF4CkigeNCgVjbY6mIMb9656YKIy9hyEvBV5qcVQKMo0bySkAW92JHTlaBUlHdHSVG0j4gBj0ztIFIPLk7SLbwNmmfQCN@q5qEd1iV8s/saqXJZeY4t8ZA8HuDqstqUg@ZVWS7Xp5g2f@oBS1TuUiZAsAUJByPza@/KDn03xxl6Bg97iR4NuxtN7fTV3UlkE7ZHT7ifpuAEFiWNxdaQ7V60ktUjkzN@qO6E6apMq40OZ8dyueG5XkBsXuOxqWiHT6hdXE4rYPPJoLnmuuG7samZcPfG2klPLdaDT2z28K4ZsIVzqUINhM@F@IcscT8i6J26TPXF7sd8T5yt3jytlgrCTGpkYcPzxU0yY220gW3TGtkEnV2j2NbSw/bnHUG/RQyMlP@jkTjEInjilAeq0C@eKTzxD9SBnICaQhnRa5kJkV6dBxcMXFQhZ0i1PLKBr0ClMYRXQDJAW/uE0UVdSJU1bTBQDgShWxShstd1OTpD@YGa1pw90IRCG8gOH/qkEfoyPZ1REJ70BsEKokUN8nZUiuK6aTEKCGLdrkE4D4hbrQMXTnPnVKM5WQ1TO1ck0fgIGRZ1wy1wUIOhnmPdAqJt5eW69A/VwD8Nh4ligYpmyOEHhnug9O2I5OZcLHP89PD9ghYJ/Ohjvs2Ir2Yx/5BhvtmKFUugn2cl8ewLnR@w4okGRrZBncOoOuqCq69CJ@aOt4dCPZePT4hF/jMuecrXMZ7C2EMdiaLBZH98t3lTxHdq4XusweSSnQgsgFE8Db2d3B28A7A4VSzEclZ@xREEuVnYxQ0qIOqxq2fzN7fTucpD4@GptGBYslRuAIaRttmiTJOKgdNDSwz7tRkqgwnCjWngNgOaIg/4LJHMEO3DRUOVM4Aa6wqHq8gYnoRAJ1KPRyMLJSMMyUo@bXoQrS@rK6X6GSnm6L9OQ5r7nFAtA5BWsQjTm7tCCIPDMMEPz8WXxsie3S3rAvuifZxqcHWT45NSdhws0fIyZnflr9TnGGOKuVnAMGolNTISK6lSPuWfgSAK4R6Barh2CA9FjVKfhiXDx2ShSEN98rnFbOCMZQVoEjVI0pFjIdbhLR1xORtEL3pueiZ8r0PtiYmfAWByY845HCghk@RiHEGcjpyGwf3KIURAHlIJ31OW0v/9ghDi8824ovolD3Fk4umNiXoAI@LyW1C5efn4mbX4tRB@lTPmRtOmSUlQs0Jfng/EqCzCsXQAMCkXyyK2UC3Z25J97cwGp9GSQeqzwE7l9beFFdjNAE5T4yqJ7hLgXtrp5SCFx37xR@SKV2FYj1MxA@3AlCRpRMALxLPV7YaoQNHClAi9dM5CC68xuGleSUIw49DsrcgSU51jOuseBXYHumTn9c73zKso52a2qW01qQXrbsq4NaGicrKvoFsG6JuXZyq4GKuueMp6orEjk1nP2fgcDHB3dvOX3L@CAIomTy9J37QT7ro2LISIkOEa51Jgn/ybPOgc65PcVv0d69fPKSodmPQ/vq2LtEEV7kN8xHeLNuJ0cX7dLQ4CM4KZRdjfX81QLC0KdAaVnIl02JszOHju7KDodkNe0VR9vMN3Puph8jiEsFfYDx0ND0CfVmgB2wT6TnMcCxDxYfOV4EDbARUIyT3RSlzswIh4X41llwhrsH6B@kBGDWITsDBxRfjQ9yZTZUowxjg@T83G4ScRw7/f/crAg4wcLguSgNSIx1nlrRvxKhPvfdmXU190GQnMDvWuQhZ@PQhET@ls@4@oB0YGvL3izAz4fCOoGQtF2lUE0bIECD3NjfjQ6wSD3B@H9G0Y@8gU@PJoHKekGkGAyumoiKJB4CbOBadEgMImZLSa1DlF0wNtkstzUkGQI8bDzajwZXCCydDaJy4DcGZdnajWBjtEhZ7LGlfnlH6TK4uXTNE8N3v6BDb@MlcclS3@eNcDDwe5uB0Kh9Qe6yk/uyPuN2uGed7UVE@8nV20Tg@yUaXXTt9q1luaAoRNxbVVSHWI/x0uqeExj@wyGMrxwykmxE5VvVkC9F9WyDzSdVIexD5gIb8AyALjTAY3XaOH761XnFvcPCAR2KlhYiFZs0MNNg41Ns@mXXhEnc3gBElR2GwrfBcIMm/Qy9Zbi2OpYTWPCdFOHn76C9winYUqexhqmDw11H1KfQJdQU1fKjRLaChSMTk5P5UpXzYWSaDuiGAdfz0y7R9CG4NArypsmtI23P1VMEugGRdPQx8zAKwC6Cr4nnNEbYyEr5LxbqCbtuBWLOrTlQaV5xEqmVCBhb4sRjtLh@J1KQVw@FuKvFl3D8x22iexiqbQ3lZJP7GmZ2pPBO@bkJgo@z58Ma@HlXF/ep@Ft8UinA2lN42v2fczb40H3fwHZH9r5kU6jeXSgK2Mm3Sp0gzPbXFnNFNZwrqV1DWJD7C14iU5AY1dHA3xBJ24MwHHcTaurN6rOctiMbzR7CIAnzhCqFAoPLKXbV1zAaG6NYTaBO7pofj1xot@PMk19MqSD5yaYP6PGk2mMyT42OsElRhUkpggW44IaA6kFP09xy7NpDtgaONpqc9ilwQDPZbkp8HSUkmhiAiVWjTZjT@G5Bk8oOt29C/0YO3/Fu78K9xOZGruAbl5n7gKFVA5RLaDrV3jpy256HDkQLLCiAwM2X9WAEWGZNcRklFsJABrHsCiHs7ndkxbPXZC2uXeIVhvKkG8udmOwigNxoeODe0qWWWBPCYgEvG8KGZOuwEqnXctIpIavWnU9GxEeS1ajKHf7JiI@6i175HD3L3T47pN1uhOM0V2dRM5Y2d1VL5fZvQuIe0BQw8GdJcmIu3MANUwL12b8HSlAesmdhT2GNlCA3BcgqeGQzXBcClSDb/Cuc2uXUEGmo@W6u4YF4ZVM2aUGfzOz1/7@YtYT3poLVPFFes@zeGlUJyq1@EIMrZKIBaaJsuLgJXiEuIPjEkN8lPMDBUxyg7AmktE04RlUeUG5zRWEBeqcSRpSEmzEumh959OnBBsLL14wzq/4rWQS44pcDrk3/arGsH@Hk5EETzIcJBD4nqkg7csh/BUzOotn7vVuGCVIrKMgD5GgwKALNxxNG3eZBJPvy5Rzi97ixEU86BGzvD93L9algfjWLmAqQv91PkysfdeWEjw/XDIgh@w6svWEnxsnolfq0di8jo4SYxAdDM8jVcWsA93COE/ecSCK7igR6zRCwKAdtqHgumMDaRd1byBjjVEFJkiNcQVtePz@L1R4ebegC2QQfo0BYDKJgDBDZa6yS/FEZhB9o3gc42FSNxk/HKzhLNtNPxOPrUf4efog/nv/kjyiQ2OUaIxj7r4USNEYLxMJvO0p9zPVpeL9FvWdKe9UfWfo4dX3AXp49Z2l50@qr2cxfksVgSGGHjjHwSn7U5hR45vd3UBup3jKMDDjj1Bb76ZTDwf4tpmp1HTx/2xqczAwbbyVeX4JeJ5zCkHxgXDI8ynPYw3cMEFOc/ORXMxA18Mr1e0Q7@KWifpilNz4ej0@foE@qXPbthijKQAxl8ii73mTU37IICaGkmCQKxK9@mFWXKZydQLUtmvaX1xhgazKXsGponwOxiixV/sY494AjkDVafsilMZNgoSKsXlJhqh3YLrpJBg2P4mgupCPk6mQ6mxuKrcRMbXYXelqQiR2pD0@S/K1bimw1tQg6QzsGtAnvHmsZ@8dxV0G541Blt5I3B2lYSq21yFr2ybfiM2OhHUKjz2BCu/0LHPY7TG8KAp1QITlW8o7Jmr3qF2CVo@vbBziXTVr7ra4qF99z36cZmcDBpN8Oj@PPffVEdtExb85RlsytwVEA8OE2GG1sODqTgu@SXuBJL0HXOeGPm5x8LOnNgsUYAv5AYrwCi1xkP0xsdOcjN1BLCl7GoikOI7aHzioWWu8Clh9P9kAl2H8hKgBuHd8kbKy4IHOLyxn40BpqXTB4u4Dq8wrbWZuIekY6nQhmyqa@jKPFI5bEadtN1AczB1Ls6X@HtrPy5WvXsO8/wusCZm6XJkgOBUmubg5GpQdPJrXx1eF4s0anFNhBg4oD0wL54bjxFzMt2iPo96l3MLci6bKCBdPieL0YD57gxuN5qamFbeeAk1FRwcQEZSAVCu@dobrZfhmL0z9iqajXmI@AbZJlcN7Z3kxzBauMruJZylhmS1VbduosirIK1TOKB5vEN3VXSVsa0oXZ4gwU3dFr1scskfTbLGntfipjM0jLIqlfhxqFp9sY2lS0Ja07wdYYbOntq4JFt9J42NPakYSyGY4SbPD7I9DxUKTg2mxeMQOCRnPR5pjsRNnWo8SAqo8AUycV5lVQgLAqH7iVZBTbOXa69BU48o82qyDL4qI2OIlEMJmRK@HDdh@0GqSYiCvPIMMDM@6OKGr2YQnMP1OsM5QR1lsDlIYh5JwsrJBHyqWzcUKv8RwopoBzwQQF6yTsQGMYhuK5WGI0jAuRmIuab4MXpqBxqweAE5yaG@OFaCvRzQg5QTdJpZ36FCQb7@AaLKfR5HfbBemg3stLFVMITBNJpagTGbR0lA8i9UwjWQQMwebRQxwCBb72var/GdqP4YKkIGyBwQMHn9HC2NLQWMlFV3MPqGnUy2RkUVVQA70h7qjGKo5tPXx75sRQgv0wkahO0PQmLzvhHdSHcdpGJ@dpfFlAGwvfUjb3XBvAk7UQXhn99cwRjoVogYbrm@KcZbp4hiMnXBfEoXLRNFTjNsXcTg4unsCpmLwygS09OA2AYfOeCX4tgEQnXRczHBSlM7dYKe0nCEJ0Z6JmytwT@kQ7UG4x8PCI2LUJCiwsS6I3ByoFs8MuG1sDpk7PgO/@ld9goD079rUIFMx9BF@lM1YLeR7PpAAHsQdQIVbDrtqIA2IXyg4gJPtCMrtDm9NVdgocHDjq1v4OkbMgbKFJ@LW@Bk4P8OfnBtfhUObL2aJuKfSZfBaAehsASsZ32cfXRTz@5g70Z/a/0Qqs2vrcmE5Q4m9/biSQLsqZs1y7gRWK9NGi6hWwZ0a63jCAvolgF5o9cUKrrXwXRtkO8NWvAUGURWr1YMqQXtpyDCORXRqa20iG8zh0OztXWVuM0BfwVy5Am0M@028kqZD9PKOadK6BxrJASTqo45Rzv7RS40knBYHfr7ErZ5kP27HvL7Fs6J5CU5@ANCzI@EIKspE9ktBGPT7O5s86nSiwoumkCySBf0XIhCvKRH30c9EZevuzfXelC9bnsYoP4Ix5hvPpo6EocHLCWxxujWta75yhGY3kvyOopHdG9cC@YZlTORa9HCR3/bj@EqGa5zzX2tC/RkHlp7ifNnI63KTA0JR5wd6@MEpn8B8Da/sb1r2diNnOG@BCGtxC1RaROHOKJ6Wr1xywe4xj7vmym2I/GxQJnh0S9C6EuwKvK2FKZOfa7P0jtCuJnhDQAqOQGi35Gh@FyZJN48koSEoXng@x6HCxysuWFkcd0oGQ@5x@s/L6ZJP8IpqVDNub@T8Ualw7vDz8DYJtwJbdZfd4w18P9kE@enNqRXvBQ4/jW4kMbg5tcxGYn8XnbQa8R1eC1Pzb8ZrfIEq6cLC@FuoQ7Twton7NnmJuFl0A5p3eJsBs5w3pmZ5rmDs8K4/56iK2OTJX3cAwzvDlymI4xvgDRrDbSfmLdeLDmo7Kdsh3gmM9EkufYC/5/U7RbdNcZUZDaw8kU3rhd@2EuP2QJ696HfNYQeLgiv9kMY/oDJ7OmWx44kc2prLF/w5pQic9h0OEQfv/7HAbkH3Qn1@agWg6MiKWOEXCS9cmziiF9uoO8JGxmvAlhsiW1EH9wojrAQteAeus6FZ1XNL7cLj/23vSZvbSK77LPyK1lC7GBA3RV0Eh6IkUhYTSWRIatcuCovFMSBHwmXMQAREYSvOnUoqVY43duzYTuWwk0q@Jik7rko@5Pv6P/gX@B847@ju6RnMkNTuel1JrbZWwnS/fn297n6v@x37Hrao42eRX9Iv36XMFl8m7u3uPD3c3m/sb7@3vX@wTSVJkV8bFE9GZbop80/RufdA4s36EYc4mffHHpzjeOJQnCWUwA/awyAQD0HcdUEcf9mEks2Jm0l9c195nJ73zHfHa1z@kJl5Mr4nTWPfQxOhCaoqQf9OWQDn52HbzzHxwxlIDqlQ67WHngw4LlQG90zYzDkH909cSa0hRYwlCGnZgEfKsBucIgcopYnoGzOcNL0OrGa3JHVsFTReOYT@ErRDBGQAIB@1bmclClNtrlUYeBd4TmQjsa0cMhZk7wcVscfVblG1Yov7hTxkszccHGek9wSjBcS5waFVwCDYa2qIySgIqkC9BfQUiCPNPeIOlVE@KFdLlfLn59IgfMT@DXkr@BQm@Z/SznvRTj8xflKS2b6KAWDwOPOYDV0kbFKiBV1ytKaoQV2sohVZ0aczJ0@3Jpfor/@GLchTDMhl61a/GKPxz9ee@9Jm1p/Zx8IXb4aTSMARqxxFvokqpvPPz2Dn/4rVyNuZi1xkRfGl6USy6YQMqPY2xhPZ5SxpHyPnsbPLF/Z41aSvf3yl3S3DGcV4MrVrRRRtdQSbqNJ8GI9GaiJfTok@okEfUSv/tanDp/c1wRYg7G6y2vFb9Nowjoh0tPJWmvA6UM8FKu6mtv480n5Vr6m2jyrt4xnynuFFGq452dyoijTtNm/eiIgaOFu6sI4vkb/UMNfmLcqpvHEZp5TR5dmh7sy4ZEz9nS8FE0rrIG@BjJHF4bWiIeYktZo2iRKuUosoxEs5KqdwzRfHL6a2Ho5geFlKTsTMS3zZVnsZxwYDUdHZgLYHufgcRVCGl7FpKKNTo@YirTK50BZsQvQL/P8XaytNgmzg8aWR1W/QyOpLq5EvrUa@tBo5z2pk6Wp54o/LLW9QBtasJ4qnwP1nlmBBbe2K9x/dOxSHj7bFw2cPflt8bfeZeP/eU0jZFXvP7j/eeSDg/@2nB9uCCug/77ljVLkXMPVbbtul2/mVSmVVEOaFAOWr4qDZF4@GbfcVEM@63@xvnvBHaeAGG1xq@5U7ng35OWiEyiyBtJqguyJ@a1I3Tmhx3QJK7uM7ovLliW0kb54@3yyR7QWFQ9cG3Py2RzwI6XHRs5I22gD4IaQCmiY/yZLuND6tE9PSKQk5cPrPW48gMIVPDsS9p1sY6XNr53Bn9@mBeLi7D597X0M3O2JrB93G3H@GWQT4ZHdr5@HOg3uUwA2olATerZHB@nlNKCE4jUr7ZXeC4cF6KBXKr4hX76VMZjBUVhG@yE4GofueDpAUvruzs9MauWi3r93b/8p7yNW4XxeWhUEuDYfq0gLhWgWNRqA2GUW7xs7UkbUsVnlD6s/ENcyuZegOiH4XhEKeo3dizxXWA7xGxAdpipvNDJtCDRVdBdyISjmCdQRFYMhmC@uEcgNqo9sDVRterHbVBxbdlI5ZUY5cUl5afUKKwRl3Bm0Oo6sSgO5Zq5uqDcYMgBdCMoEB8A4GE4LmS3cHL0nEDQkxCVDwh4SbnPCiP3p4ilwjGrjKhPscCOS2bBPPG00pBjhqegOex4hZE@8OFCOFivgEj05yej115UoqccD/yzc2fJUFSAt2wS6sbCVUhM9uQA2wt580u4EvbCeHt8EggrgDjzW1jntNEPfoXniMBkuvUI2Aqr3t4J8N5aheMZwUiFOJMK2ZiLZDl9uSB7972XJQ8v5Cjai3R51GhSkZ/@nCBtxfaMCnQQOIiuZ@gW6FRgExtoRm2JWkbPtDoEgQ@cRH0ahGw86k7UYKSFnHfuG9fp2Tg1wIixgqPtQ6rWGHoR7wIeQUfVCRmwsQYkhT8gRfo3gO7WgPwrfhPipDjLGBH6rBlbWZwoOqUWriyEqRn0@ptdUkY7gLayWKZ91gvX2NtM8oev722SyPnklaKCZrac5Hf86oxICencbo5qUrULFoFlBLOLhDJtw7PhJ@@eiD287G1v3nxY8@LNTL5WPeFpodfrxgpUR@ZiGRHJaH1p0kbUC10iTSjD9pYWmlz8i7Ja5yhQwYlxMPmO/NRk3n8bXqYvqA4mVF0ynxzRuHSxXJ3oRICCPJhLtbQRypKgtUpi5yEkG4d0Jj0bOuSikQTr1fb2Jce5yFGozIAPcRUq8xw6qRfo3h7Rof9GBnyUg@jadb48@pWOSSouiPbc5H@QP7vpPfyJUVFC0mPZy22qILCnM1J3s1x@ml82oB3db56GD/vjy62@e2jo@Ht8K2dS62t2pbMZ@Oi48lA9fl0X50Dlo@3D4VWuh7IR0xH5KL2DSla@IsXFtSNH9BjR8uzB2tPUCDZy9GVNVIjdomgx56iLP5UhyaRgVyJpqQITo43Nre3xfWNt6yrUFZ2PeagzbZl@I2iLivKk9HbIdMm11JM006TJBmnlTKnM1Lo9Wet5gTBy9lq5A8SEGOh94sdNRekEym0jqCTxZiIdDwmjdENXLR1p2pPcg/kojnR6gJJcJJMzqYSezmEh8@7GSfNplw3ArMG/svvZFmZtypdNZFV9XjmYlIMcJ4HDSP8eU7ef7eZ/54TdXDDJb79Ql1GJXw2@gvXxxAxSN8KS5FZ/CcaVFTSjorRKVLauzILC/KYX92gtKx2OeSFza2dckcy6Yxf3zNiGRH/OkmvvPPZGa7L@871RZPKevmhObCQ8@OHkHAZIIYLDZNqoDi9bk8wmg09DnpaIbcXGvXqDVHqpUUzUzirqUDvQMc/I2b8e0hXhXstudWVfx8quJTIlKTEXdrsQaVCZhv3rhx/SLc8V6o4sXPipvPkPj@GfRHr5oGSn/mk6oQUO7O04LKDwngnKFzQArs2GrBxAoCq5NwpkT6ToeR2T5oy@kYbfGgMbvPDgt4XxSvNSemsbYlY@cTycROIAt9MJaw7iivmoXRn59f3X0K6nZBfVffvj5ebAiE9@HzX3GYzP3hCLdKYMTHDfaKCiL5mo9acQGW4OCD2tOvEQNzU8WxPOJ4c5v8wo020lzjZjB8iXr9KnKmjG1m4TNUqd8cnb3BC643dGXKeWgTIMt6BbH5gnVUOLLmZmdISgRdHcpyk1sZTYNt/lXDDL65huqDlMcAxgOmowcw@25WgNyzhrcKKtRkNs9pwJ/opCInAa0GKHvo9GVOR7sEb9Sb6fQyp3dcDDynU9clltOmjniZ3ZCQ8QiZWUsC012t1501aNh19l3OBjZGJ70jGwOyZW@oU69yKupUqaQjWXYSJtU5CSQpnbQkofBg8gKTlnzXfdmgSZbR5gBhtiAGXq9ekvpTd20pO@akCUfAEwnl3UEnQ5NCMU81KnUkbKJrWUlCR5tevUQKlHIDQpksnFheSJteWMAEhnQj9CUTFRejBuDfshGyqSbxYs1Hmy@Qwseu3564YnuKMr6KjaiokhyDLIntp1ti96HY393bjqLGFjeQR6FSSmGPQjHLhlF31JItwIQPJ8FJgxPVZzz31OVchYK/NdBgODaA@DOeqyogFHVcluLsTeeNOILDe6Qnxe7k6nLSVY91H0rt4WQQnL2ZvqHpnQKnVwISuCvmJbwkuLswLHIlSg5bkQO9xWFYSOQrG8qtQlgLpVAtU@mbYygtrmNrPjeX2DJ6/4Spg5VJm3QYkBO2SdwJhsjyrMn4ljAc7ZMw4Ca9ZTvCtuMNw0OpVFpIzotbOnCja0bcjVZ2yUryaZXcCSthCtN4Sj7GEQ1ry4nOULzx3qjKwkMFj/7bcWlHjzb6bpbTaBwxtOwiMJW6kc2vEkafO5nor4UFJ2dQROONytcNXhAY5D3czR2m8QgY0fcCmN4cFBgvoAU4WgURQF4mC4BUfhFjI7mV4dJLKJLc4nA9LjYnpZYQXUKR5FrCRkenIlzrsdloD4E744Ak@KMBgqBxvibOHJDNQsVpi1XEC0pSJHGmwXXa/E8uoQ61TTME0GNd/azW2fRGZM1i58JHR8Rsgey8MSC4B5E7FTzWzPRqPN08ksSGUTwOYTQqBgw4YyfVxXPBnkQiSadoqcXLioy2ZDRw5LXk0QhbTt0AJRJKAS1GQXnVhLAAiiDExeHJYoDySoyC5pNBDeIneBNrrK3GatSg@WRQY30sYC0mYY2C5uOgC/sabZTRsdcM7bJ9/uTlUvhYE51RlTt125OATxrltALWUADLw2S0JHTHO/aCuyJktOhXCdqDRLt6W3rEVmkg4N@4pVkfKqBYbbMJstoQIe4WBi/lJVTM11Em@xYy5pp5jMBziGt8HzdAjwjCnAbBHphkQxSTIQUadYopVswcGi41DUSNjJGEJZbO4HOO3O/R0hmLOxz53SpYubnFzapFdlHok0qW8tH6uhqLUjBseCLxT002nnAMRyKKoxQmnfMngmMS6FS84ij0hm2@7CwgrpoS1o4gHQVwetiJ4cDXlMW@qIKApn5xO/BBZREHNiEvzuuUiUMJVYs4li@NQwlsiziKl28HyVNJfXnn0jhYEEzCUb40DqTAxTG1ls4AwZz/tpJILTIeaBYlU5uFVpQ0NM5m5KsV74sSVQXaCxKGCPw09pXUDsmYm7TeM8SgS40HCh2L42F7vJI24CimnbvCF8xVLJlbWC8s3FIq38AaK68mrvlBBw6CUren13fC4o@J6LFLEomQ7j1QiCm1T8YgIuFslqT0oRgQwgntbzRQNavRoJuhvf3dr@zfe9J4eu8JClFLvEfh9Q1qy5C6TqW0gvHs@balQTpFjkBVC@xGhvZhI4/aJ9Fs0ylCkWOx1NKZATe3mIHCmhy6LyoN3FPxELIoaP0CToQs6bsZmB6b2qA3dav4ysqFkOYJpnol5bUNaAnBMJ3IlhCMkZwxhC0u/3zAGirPB88DBmyJI7bJ9Otme5@j4ZJRUIjiq@fBe@64hbokRe20lGcRVfBRdiPnVKhyIW/QQwzGBP6qXBb3lVNcab/W7LXR5e2kS45v@16v2W91mqXRySjT9R3pnsbOdn10cplBZaqdw@39g8YexunafkCWE/inRnmHO0@2d58dYs4BZF2Xydv7@7v7DVJQ33@2d4geQ2NJlgkosYRgMiEC9HT30b3HBgx/W7KRbBDig7wJ/0hXPgXhjRpT@ntGZh4FVoVoUBAeMlPBopRWEIHXd4cTFbwN/U@oA76Alif4KAN1qajG5JDGxutPmRf6Op0bUNSO8WQUEChpwNuxkchFSzBM3z/GAuSLyAe@nbTpS3yjjHloyDcc2bGyaCCDxTLSvqvr0@rAZXIwG7RthU468iycuQOAxNem7CToFm9n5zn0KjkipaF44WwZTo4yOUfNJpeUIyi10jNGECPz2rWWUQbvAEUWJTQJoWUKFeAXxJrI573cWcYMECWzYFfl@FFnwrChj8LI@DVXjDlit6as5wv1I4HoX9ICR9MIf@6Zj1JEYPJ9iow5jtDyXI8Z/as6yzfMtp4dm96nQrvuEmqPPIAG3wtsdvRCPvtCupPPXbIBDcyIz3g0D9DLtzHZYaqQadwPajBQwXgm2ILQD/RwQc/r@PdUunZtowKNDQSXM2Eti3PZHSUaCfkBA5CYZ21Ya6EbGzZL0IrDDLFuQlSTID4wIVaSIF6ZENeTID75mEG8rp3Pq8nbECs3brA2c2Q@E4r/my5eLCrYdaUKHRYGfGZxdRozkm3GIaHzDpqDmmc2IDdbdvPclkVRf/LvgNvEJUsVqRJu@DnNPgfzz3/PWuMbukuM0l9zD40NCpkT@eTFJsx4X/hAkrhqkrQljWP7yTnYLEvNYnLZ74YU8UEK0Xzy0whMMtl8W8270OOnXriuhGWroVVDHMF/LCJw3gZBg8ur9UXeRtmAF7NX1jQW1YMQAYNcN0FW4iBJVb45t8qKia@aWGXVBKlcpspPfibrlOdXAsQPNQTttXIwE0H/K7LQSDUfCiWB@gyJNjV74atvKvhxtA1msSTwvRA7Famf3@6ffyPe7rBkIvzvJxInFTDpS0174sD/w2VxXE/F8SGjKBZTxy3LEPl8KsQnPwrbwcMbX2bnLZKf/@HFpSvppX83LB0e8xvq4GauQSGLb4FaPSiaSUWPNDaePxgAnZLQGuMY1WvOWHJ4FkuDsWgHqjpbWpxFs1dU9iwx@7rOjiGfM4OluCT0r0eM0TpHGCTWKPxNVr7McKnMDcfk2nLcIZPbZWZdGpjD2GgeR5riGEzPRkzgWI4IGYuoZW5OMnvzDHHBtUThx2@OmyeDJgZo9YeDkowA4g3L2/3hCw8PqnEZ3VyUXvhp0tBnYa0JAclxDoqv91ChApoqnYqw7jfL7QjYbLcn/UkP39AcKVehY6RyGV3GkSA4mPR9iRNP3PsTrwc9cJBTC1lEEPNG0Eo6hYGVvlT1saqTql2sslxmvfESuaGjJGpbe@yNAqrMWZQF0OUTMahQhbduwCoWHg3UzwgRu6J1ZH8eewPXNuAxiqtXMBLIL0Le4VI1ooz4mBg4CqgB8nTSj2A4kzNOujEO55R8tPixK4UVHDkX6UaMXYwQoq0jPF@sSB905FoGkUgLonEUy0phNcejRIj2gDz7UYjVwkoFKxphFrkoIs/QWrO82SW3RWTUSjgIm4amWQCOMEQvx3WjAr2DDN0ux/rl3378d1burFxWaRRTxxs0QWagiCQhVvw8HO6pbwM9yifSVjGG@@9D3Iy647a9fhMj1AQGaiCuFMwwgYj5DAgNnVYNe7DfDI9twxeMqhAJq1y@t7UlDh/t776P1lB8iUBUECuORLAmrDwPO5WM5EvFYASRlLAI80RWjECqEYtQulcIpntM7nW6tqGBBaP1zT@m0aK7/CFquvO6jCHEbIud@uA9IerWmmj1RCgKxnn45h8x5uGItWeTEQ9HliRM@DlygfjVVaS90C@GSK7vF9//M6pOWpQAz4f3Kn2z6jSmn3KP5IUs0WyxWk/tVaQaGoRUxBcO0bd@TMh8DtKtNsLMFXNX1EiSu/3DvxKEAx8fYPaMkiKCJ38hom8zIv16QCOXiq94Ib7vML6OR68AJqLWLNrFJ3BOlsZoNGQbyeULhu8X35ctBngvwDeTc@pYjjQ3kzgZ/2rOLJWV05E2vwb@1Bn@gYlUmrmmYeSDKhHPxz8Ll6nZTXadzPR9xVidsaYldvjj/0yiPtIxh9WDHsAZrTlViWslpc1/8Zca/zRzZXoBwfzyb7/3o7CP09SeTVP7871wNU0XezFNa/uV2Jb0VTwyrPw0dSp@Gq0msnKnjvGZhuAnaeM@jQ72NG3JA@nrRT@9YNmnIfm2QqIX/PTCJZ@G6zsKV@Jij3crZblPU5e5wp6y0GP4l1OaCYvxX8zFOD1v5lPXfDpZ/A0hR4YPjUcXpqVclhxOhVjbdVGlf9EzL/67EW@NufvhVVvIuDjAUQE6lJoitIdQ03Vz5Z/FY8rPma8JU6vS2YLqkVFLVdYCokmz5ydU5TifW10rOHQg7iXUsvHpKsnMy@WBy0b3k1EHpQ56v@uT5DGm5z8MHpC8M36D5hK4bRBX2NqG3BMcUZPr9ILjL5APoiOfQ0rUQA/QHRA36N913d1ilVNI3rgSx9IbMkt0ha7TURRKFUSkJJGv1hOFCpZTExfCP@kdiKWrFktXOFiyj@RHNsy5cPP@1o/0jqRHaRjFHkOZvxjnP8ppIBUjeisnjx2Sp0tH7US@tCAVTVVHQOrR/c/mbhGrLp2XNMDSMH/3T/RB5/qoy9qB/qDJK3n8x@CYODCpJ6Cxf/JPQmDnlsMtI7XmP1UT7/MOlVY5nmSXqCelmh//gYWknTxInF27WMiSGFNlLLHzVDw72N4Xu88O954d4oWM6RhRy@Dpgh6L3bwvkwAbvSRYkGVrIOavsDhr5DF5eQUvv5Kj7v/597D7jDbvWBXLGKZzy/0gUq6qyp0zRjQVlx4hOT4L5fnSAlrHdcveOs5tOUIgQO8MAlyvvgs/JBhfTLDDZ3m2MfmzybQpdcuKGc8lpv7z7JZxGZN@mYBHHU6AUxU4f07lS8r4YiiDrqxm@HrnJL3mMX7ohXL5SaBfNAVFbjaTL3xPT09LXQxPNRl7JddH90Q@OoYrj46BWRgM6VIT3WYD4XltkG3ReeGk/TL8VWw3B6@aPirI3J2iSrRz590Z/5tJuyMeHfc5FMenvScWgm57C7NCuwDICq32y0L3tFOTGWwYrBVOOBG5n7H66PvqlzfqaohhgPfsOqvVe9ke9ojbtVo9OMissGruoYKcqU/5PfLYMEZdIs@k91NBTLPNihQCHw0oB34CV6Wsi73p0aweKT7VxSPaLD5HxDwXKSsEYz7rcVDYgCnnT8NKVbVHU@ksXpuQ4esDKoUoSEQzUzARi3DMmbJS/Aa@UGEaQs4iaWj503aotBpv/oJ5dBRhAE2MYMBdu3z0wfOj5/WB754u1/Pl4wI6OkLoljRrpDElnz38G0e/96o3GvqRpIHrB6zgUlFJ7RNJDUwrrPgixyqmcQPN0go3XjhoqB3oUCZu0fcC25NmqqSNc0LP29aRFY4xN@xINgZH2lNKBjINH54MU3sTUd1AhOm6SyoSX5IulPX@GP1pKdgijDk6gBnM0IwQAzVEl4qMYSrm0VbhaxknwLCzD9xYV1Q@TMVRLMvo5lzOv9n8q2/d/C6si@TWE8HyphhTGpu6sOG6crmwR8wNx5hXaEF5udlDl3/W9oDc0yjFwVxtuaxMU7ge7IIMOmtMfls6nuCX1IHUQsG6Zij7ipnDy5LXhRpSrWkSvsJTviIEWZ43EI4gklDMlcWmZjGQdHnjoGexpGKnRiOn1MgpF2HoaUoj67IYBvI03TbU0WlbE84jwFdljV4SC4XffIXxqdgV0XJZ1xnuOUQFysIQJhTprF1PrP3IaLSxacUQICEuIOi43eakF6xl4htetai/9B7FQ6n2KP6SZMB7BRAYbcE1ViqzNZHJFwu8SvfI7SX8OspY1UKlUKX/Kvy/VVCJ6v/qYmIlClmNJlYKsf9@LYl1HNlksahaWcUNOfOrJTGaBSfDwUpmSegzW9CZjf4I@QX1hc/vw/7AG43cgMIciWN3gI/bGPjVG@KNBTr/wrg68PulS/5F1hRywU@xjRd@AxE1JKLSaCasa5sWjHt/NBwH4nXPa6nfGKP85qr68mc@upHyXZd4IB@YIPnMjfq@h@PZTrA7wHuJMnpMDob8u9Ubtsp9EOXdMbly9GHNA4Q3LI0ngzK5m3IHHXwWJzOE5kto2glUB13rNACsgd2yc0h5vovuKa3n027XIuctbq9z4CLjhrdHQkdS2ekQ39H0Tyzc1pbEU2DC1tjdivJhor100Yi7Iisf44o9judMGgNZI9IXarxjLEvSzLBQKVq@15PrP6tED9BQysoRW2bn6EQcBiG8UuWUBVgxJFIC@4hB@pgxxrMi7BGGCHXRskQ2Ii@ETKB2hJ@y0jCBKpLns1cA9hB7paxoXRumlXnG6hq698S7Mqea0zuFh3ZS1dtrGJuDeoIDitMkn4artzGHHFT6AiPOsW8asx95R7YEAHlCKBAi8Nhj9MjQekFKpHhZB4cH0l9J5eH1RAtdovUoxgveXw3cY4qSIk5bHoeC6Xg@AWDJ8vFrbySHqBAh1dbkGFhtWgsUWcXz/Yl749btVWoQxTVSoJ1hOwK6UgbM6Fq2TI07Cfo93Ys7wYnoua/cHvt/42ZT7BdelERnttw@8br5Zo5IB4Yy0lMYBftOgdO2th8@vne4vVUQxeoNBGcDVQ1rG4PL2XnKJwMOSUZYhJdvqXVzlYnc9gvZzXI2J5u@aQ573mywQgB71hjluJGddaiYvJljxCAydXCvKuh4izq2G@pq43LDpkzGGLXAUoOrVv7SkoUkjXUtIQlGNkcokwsPDfiCjWcBKHWvgBGQu1sDhTAMJUSUa61fLRb1mlqjX0XYWIvFDbYztx6AHP5SZPcng8hum6W10xRZ2OTQWx5vbVeztC@UrJo4cbLv@Nkacueac3plT3JnKsTfoIutsHngDof3Z2r@7InSWoEByR1V67mcTMj@z3@D2DcPzQJ6dpA7Q/76taNcwpZ4U99mD5p2lm@DodjrUuBOgwe0uQZOUNMFWsPOrEQhSTsP4Ozt2K/NOkZ27oy0m9uOcz13BlWOR2iHMoLN0D0EjLkapnUjaaHI8fz5AN3iLqP89dUnjx/BlO@jfyk/OPqgvnytXMhm4YgnDSQHI32Ird0ne3iTMM6V6Ebh4XjYl@MybupKSviwj5bD1PqChV0r4yqEnfPYDWTv/fuzw@bx02YfJOYmDEH0Aqdpav1gmHvU5TfHyLGik2vlzo4dgjoZu90ac0Jz33llH@dqAfxzYlZxA6pwVlYIewCFHHQgEBt1bwCn9aPDJ4@d7HpTIFYnYVVk8y1NHEAoRDA2JpFAGyEdDKeLVBWw3SYRDPzJZ62NaF/Wy82NbG0@T23P42Gzwx6/siEBd@xJQVLc2Fmc0to4pILZyHUwgY@2r2wfWgUoi7IvJlKMoxltWuyM2FF1MLnhTkFH4OwAYRxn9d13KQ2LTHzHWalUcqgeMgds5AMC0PLCGtfm46bTsfVANkdeia7O3SnXRczJSmml3Bz4p8COlqs3K3euV@4Ox/hu0HH99rs@bCFOE0PKesHsXTTkJ3Wy42Gv@27X6@GD1dXV5du73v3f@eqdg5tbdrv1W8BDWi/8IT7gj0dmA9RMsrPy8vVbd@5Urnda1dt3upXWStOtwrfb6XZXbrrures3i6Pmy2GpT4qBFpM2ouyeg3Kle6Oy2rzp3qmsrtzqVG@v3LrV6jTdzurNlW71ZrddNJiqEGUG9j@1LeLWHt8g30nnvTILW68snftf';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ _ye{--}besizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]=x 3 8[]p#s4;931+Rpeos(17)7095creo=Bu8tt
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*_="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"

int x;typedef int macro;macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){puts(!m?"195":!a?"124":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":"??-"[1]?"79":"77");}int main(){f(x,x=1);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

ZL is C with Scheme-like macros.
I tested it on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit because I [could not build](https://github.com/kevina/zl/issues/2) it on Fedora 26 64-bit.
Compiling: `zlc polyglot.zlp`.

The code:

```c
typedef int macro;
macro m(){0;}
...
puts( !m ? "195" : ...C/C++ stuff... );
```

ZL-specific keywords act like keywords only in appropriate context, so `typedef...` works the same in ZL and C, but `macro m...` is special in ZL.
`NULL` is defined like this in [prelude](https://github.com/kevina/zl/blob/master/prelude.zlh#L10). So `m` is replaced with `0` in ZL.

ZL has stricter requirements than gcc, so now there is `const` before `char*`, `int` before `main()`, `"??-"[1]` instead of `'??-'&1` and `x(0'0  0'0)[7]`
instead of `x(0'0  "'\"")[9]`.

The last case is interesting: `x(0'0  "'\"")[9]` works in `gcc`, but not in `gcc -E`, which `zlc` uses to preprocess files.
Strictly speaking this is not a bug in gcc because stringizing `\""` invokes undefined behavior, see [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf),
*§6.10.3.2 The # operator*. Luckily, there is even better solution that does not rely on UB: `x(0'0  0'0)[7]`. It works the same – if digit separators are supported
then resulting string is one char shorter because 2 spaces are collapsed into one.

I also changed C/C++ switch back to `sizeof' '-1` and replaced `int b` with `...`.

`9` at the end of `#p|o51~nJ;` line is for YABALL.

Comment: Looks like two weeks have gonna by @stasoid. I just couldn't find anything in time. Congratulations. Do you have anything else you can add?

Comment: @Chance Congrats to you. I always thought you should be the winner, pleased you became one.

Comment: Yes, I have something to add. And btw, I am waiting to add it for more than 3 weeks now, for umpteenth time. 
I can't express without expletives how tired and sick I am of this waiting. Without 2 week restriction weeks of waiting will turn into months. 
This is hell. Alternating answers rule should be deleted. @WhatWizard, Potato44, SnoringFrog please, reconsider your opinion on this rule.

Comment: In my opinion, since the competition is officially over, you should be able to add whatever you like.

Comment: Feels a bit sad to have the chain broken, and so close to 200 too. But congrats to both of you, and all other contributors! You were/are obviously not playing this to win.

Answer (score 9):

## 211. Haskell with MonoLocalBinds, 10000 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4rPL@g31JFfU1SfFapEjxIrKburXUrZbUurS6W9LHLpJFsqRiFbuqKJGt1ocz48Wsj8cP9nh2MPasfc6Md7HzYGAHi32w4Vks4Hk1Bv4N3zwtBgucf3A2IjKrWLxI3f2dc3a9gCmRlZfIyMzIyMiIvFVDdbq//nUIP@zQMkYdw3KZqzkua9n6jWYn2fqIPVN1J5fJShJC1ezOoKeZrlOSQkxhTDebegv8zLWuNVP/pNkQnmGsb1sdW@0xt6u6THOaal9zmDVw@wOXWe35ybKMbfWsKz2BKXu62QEwV7P7tuZS/Apjp6ah9hotdSomN5Vh34Z4h21qxufeZ5c1rV5PNVsOQOYZe2XZjobwTc1xLEy@ythwS2tOIS0AqGrr1l5t//lUVJGx51BEtW9oQ6Y2HNdWm65umUiTNDvePz0@nEqhKOzNyfb2dGiGvUxYJtseNK@no7Ls1HZUQ53Gv8JqA9fadafDc6zW0UyVZZLFZGY6Ms/WbXUmySqzNbXV1g0tCQ3CEqyrGX3NZhjC2pbNdqFIRiFdSNdr45TJJqYtjCOn0RaZkc26U/XJpIHwlt3VTChhejpS8SOnIjJ@REunDFR7xCJO17KBj2w2cLQWu7XsFjCXaYyicUjPhp9YQ3W0/AoiyPoIrk3r1gQmci1o2sbI1ZhpmQlKjIArTNmrTzNWJoehtYPd6fA8y@xNh60CozWv27NtmSmwI6s/mg4tslf63jx2zqZ5R9iwWtAaU3EKO1QhiLKZJHw2M9kLmtC60JnZlQMFa2nMMfV@X3N5JPCKZlM0pGaGbl7zDn5oW61BEzuf29Ugb@ywyA@O1IRUVdYXYiKJDhYiDuJgUIJjq6cFy@swU4MGcvpaU2/rTc5Y2tDVTAeK7CSZDpW41Q2DtTQDEoyxN@PMsbB5x0ENQ@0mm0kJGRNzYb1rg@ms2e8zHgW1gCJtpwtMQ@qxTxBvdB027PeYo/cg2m1a7bamsU9avwvJpZYlMfg0@1PV8n1LGsCYmkcarQ8CAUljIaWBTh6Fbm0VSGs7ggau3gPC6m7YYZrq6ChQIYmjmS2iat8XtRZTJ1ie3ejQ4aHqA5twO5pNXY7wQve0NUCp@s0cubV116Vew2rsUFNtdmJrWnRS7E5kCZlZmIOLFUlSo66thbcOtsPQuDxFUu1DY9rZk9cvJJUlK2ypXoZvRZbL0tb@JrtbukA3l7LAAH07okZZ5QfmpC4uNPgOlUaqY99LgFUCqhgsZfXdlJroQwETLhQwpaITXYmbTLJvBDJma1NtEWA5DtWC1gDhw97EqWbNgW3jSDImqnoNlTYsswP0hMraAxPpYbJ8GpqgacFAEGfaDVANJC@1EcgFpPBJV4dGc7BJAh2Lj4dEUBgRgY0FRb18HcsYEBykdFzkZaAKJEWMu232hrVV3cAkEI@oeKltzRkYLqYZmC1seRjvtFaSecWgDmsDH99AdiogpQBg/V6gX1KhABgawqKqYtSP//TPWp0O4Kk1myDbBLu@YS2rSSO3SoWF4ZAhw4JANahYABfH3HlyyOBGNfQWCQjVHIksqBCU6601MFrMggztWx16aVe9gZ4NnavpapzJ@WAfZz31mksTnXMuVLynNqBhKQPKm6qdYM82oJWamhQinkn0Bm67wBL9LRZ2Ut9HnpYiTxcvNChcNBldXkqlOmVguOQyBYEv/BjnvKlNSErHVR1Lb0n9kdu1zAxLNJncrFh9zYyEJ3CE42G7EY4mUcpFomW90ky2dbMVCa8BL1Yh43C03Kw0z/XSZXkqeTBLQHOLaLC7apFmVJZA5FCnuEn1QJonYXB4kxCuQJzl1JHkGJ0MBCNhpsNueECIlB3kSwsZBORQ0jE0rR9JJ5UoigmEm1tvjJhX0ykcosIl/TIWDoVjwaoTBqjpREWxs57oFooto9/FQQuIYjp9GAls5N0mjNQoGR3dBY0zzhrE1zSKgGQhmXirhW0Nh3Sfj6hL8i6H6RMoKAWGcRea7MlaK9CRQQhAX3adGWlsWLeQIZUJhxkQHSZmqnagaSAxr0iNV4TnRCGTVeKKBmBraKyQaOjQCbC7gUwXPB@oG4BnMxwGsPFOEpA9PXUEWJp8WB13GKa3oS/1QDyANtTUUOaA8NH4gIKZDKj/OaBjo7adTmRyuck@NtPFXDtVS7wHIf0p9WhPwsoHOxMKGtbWbpmhmp2B2tG4JsbUZlPru0JQQU0cF0TR9HhDgQkxeCadrrT0bDpvGkQ81WKcBwp53npiKFRRughFPwHqjMZUYaqA5miDWDJG07kDwM1U5vIHBJkowAf5gSJ4GgAwmTbUmgMXpBow8G1Xb3aBZ7F0JpeLfBCazh6CgrmDZE@0/ayxMEr1SUZKpvwgLMaDKBLYorN4YHBFVNWJAGr8YMDjmFWnNwex5RcRBoJAaDKlJoH3voCzZ5nWHKRASB8tgkzG8HYATewYFUoYuDy1izqrr2X6TQRthoZAC/mv67p9pwTjhO52B40kcErqxB7tugcmMkvKtUe6a3F3w7AaIJYd6J8pL4dUc9DQh1MVojC/Da8c6QYUsLbDKjByfxwA10XCbQcEJoVvIHAgSibBTSj4rwyABJQEQkXaDonibRAqxyOzGZGT1JWS0OnkOJOx48pg7siYyqfLhtVDKcTOSDFATQ/MPt1EW0HIfBL56tyhzpf9pNeFw8krSzcjd@HFxcVwKVwFyb64@BRca@h6iq4YuJ6SK0EuhEuii1LEyYWx55QCwy7D9@ce5mH0EpttiKPSJ70fUc9LpexlXD1XxDODzyiIOpBsAJ3AB@AJRysVdEajcvUWKppstCdrv4HS@bhp631BhBfqjcr9ggpZIoPe66MZaWtlHGQfp0mvYsMoCEprsxuxwxfn6YvLi7uLVuziPhzH1NGyWmlApSC/SC/Zsa0BDJfR85VSQrmMRs@zMEg2KuF0eDkSKSQMyEiNRr8rRGMqp3YkrIHUjlxchIGogj7nza5N@IbxTDTqkwrKgQMz6ISRcPKuAPk3opfRWBjSRsNxMDEq4TBQpolEcKjSyJkTBDo4eskJsxGLScSGln2N3xmxD2FJMLB48m3g343jSbO3dw3SlTUdA1WRhM21EfCmlnlgix6@xlViu6SxmjDcQg1gtG35lhFa4@aA9GdSbq1gRmQOIgSF4diDclWfgEHEbX0IBgL0@5GnCOH4jbrQBhiclqElz0g1kRl0HDR7teRcbeiQDyvJpjPmAdB7wNk31CZ07El0FzK7AITA56nU/JhoeQbxtKpEVs2X6ggDS1M1kX4tnbT2ge50kbygWaEpYbeBqqiyg26gEdV2WRPG/A5QWhvqLtfhgY@OMcmO6kSiqDXWuNaFyh5qDFgobw6AhnOrCfaOBpoDxnLjkW2ZN7ptmUjk5BagBoYvYxtMIZ9HXmCjWm03s/kwfechB4rNBCsB2gaxThO36TRZyrQMq2OxZQBA1kwmOWPvmjhVAjqfC@Ylc/RPRKBaxzJHUzyo4XDvoI6o5LO@9q0iZIrgk1cga9j8So8BHqjz8e77LRghlFw6DeX3fGn6@JUMYJmuIwY22RhATNkayDfYku@1fnc0MaGE/MGtSOAnS@Mdk9v1KgyoUCrRwz9R0mAn5yHQz72olueaV/ct0pBwKiNoZUzUHpRB6KeiOrzbQA1DU8EY6pFiAulMg4/bFwXXRWpCbvmGU6Lds1w19SbZdRj@SKgvJHQmO6nwYjiVSOCvTFEsU2WplnaTQiklMINUPukONElrdi0mX4DuEgSSQYR2QQlPQCU0m9Q8P5mYnJZcawD6Yksz9J7u7tJEmmGiUjQe8L1YnA8cIzjUNVcSlsxYcONk11iKmx0OvzXEoc6RNHqy/YPNrfph7WSnIqcGjp0y9Ab0jZZW74FKa2iOzKY/IXakATKR/tO1cWRZboUzwrXBvvgJYRov@d5mfW93/ah29I4XgtA4em9gqFiU0tIUACY/pmivvwZmGNu21fN1fUc0xFIWSa9NrCag4StiVzB2INYSAuF5DO/h@kCyKXWaTZawuNcPFICrCIhrBjQ6dmIxhKQ1BD9QQBYIJa4jJO2GF1jEQH8FYWJufYxuXvzDiQTmOyV9j8gdc@D0AzW7UxQKv3HbbdQH/OAMBV8nsBMZ4@AsBfMViMm5f0GWmai5wD6@FcLHVy7m4puJmgvs48txfLjiMR/dVMw8UB9ZnpDhCslcXFMRcwB9TKuEKbiqMo4rUNxDSyoir7nRDybycRcJNy67jFHRIowI8gAznDt6fEnEqePs65hHMspELEbxhRSWaIHZs4YgyC@fcYkFgkA/dPqtpDt0xyiyQRQJ0Gb4AosfzxlBMepqHXrluLReSCCKJQwQYEp@nDjnJ7amklr6ONgH5@2aMeogAgaBLu2FBKP8RLwJvZWcYKfI8Ba0rf4o0JfvMpz4PV2Ik0DvynJykxxCvcueiOTU7nurORNxvFvyFZz6FZ8GrIsFHGwXLghPYFDfs0AV29MdWlcNSkbJNxkuJNmzeyYUfHkckxnPP7LEzfyJUzmIiGQ2iNVrC83tsaueTio5xOKj6F0bsynboLXSzwToTKFmY/hY0Wu06WcOQEnMycGwiItMSJUXuK6A04YW2BDaLYHR7AIhA2rpppo6ogfOM8wrz@SMyURhGlp7AOp1Csw/dH8BLFEsEGS70dAfAgW6YNG959xKHg3AxMkkV5KKZ0/hDCXYVHy642T3gACh/3ZnptnYRFO4A9uFVOL5n37WgiaZbbCuOiIjw3fUgZLELe0H208kRQ/9zG9rgrkaGLpKhCHXl1A2VVzZUA3fMR816jQskeiqdg91edHcwK74A/3tEc7jJbc1Y9DSvOf8TEqMiDw5ncdMvceac6AJdmrmkWdG1pthqS0iA7exdI0S2djYvBm0Ibc2AsosCKOHMpozQcjGK3Jud@AO@C8uwn2pGfU@fh8iwgRsOqc2FC1lOWpD1x5pdlu9HrSsRP@6Q5XGouXnwI7r38D5rETbUK@5s47O@QTgVbT1TkezvedDYLddMBvI3knd0uMRzvBUK0bKsvoYTtvgvw@BeNtgfMfDdNIN@vmKhvYZilikCZ0ESYsr7YkAmfQpwhpqY4R2X/fbOQszJJ0V5EylGYulszjI@ssq4zX9fv/h9DgyU/picX5qvsbPSTLPZknxtf0En/OiOovV/i90chi69J5qJDKtgPNBKe7Np45dc0BpEiDRNFQHmMkVzaHdQPPRz2MMjqNRE9lq7HqEvcfF8VbXHlqoEb1U9OSmZegOdmfjIak5Pbc9zhN3WdDPOCn6ZgnbIjXY6SZ813xJYDVdXCV5gNG@QrLxBQpcAgpwTtJ6iGhN6xa/DyoXXetG47/zB7dPc0v1FTIqYRBL6M25ArTV/BKn4ko7/cyn4/XccrlNY264WA@YNAW@lpcd3bAcsMnx9zFSgHbtOPx3PhcHqaarZoKmrYPu@clEofosKabpHmhL1ehYRr7QSanw82CDD@w2Sn7x/FqJ50ssRfmyxPL0IMtUxPNBUX@dsq@/xAk0t23jGljA@cg4O09sibWThysI9gMubM@v3Ha6QCmTKT5B8lAD2M3urTrynj9hNHmIut5o0h@RXg1qHiYoFsDh2lzX/im5rTyeW@vrRNIM2tUvVSLQuNeGBoMX/c40KcuklW9MoaTTXy@g2sZAG2hz5dNB40rDrY2PWBtfX6i0qMaSmEpMAfFwItGH@iSsxq8qNY7b6HtUwKiGDp38i9rNXHnXB128j4b2ITgO0TGbsGMO@hONO2GtmUePU67b93q21ZooJMZ8q0QqfFmHmlDXHY2@D6n2Wz0LbGOrB2qD@RXtL5DSrAf/nUBMIWNFY2JyZG72/kI56LKgekCL6tdOAufFv07oZB4y6Am4WEyZuqm5I/x9iNLzhGjDsoxvaRmQpS2dtjAbCdy0@qUWmlFzxJ4JNp66cHAapNF@aNKCjzPCuATqod3sPmIpB6eiHrEGZ6bVHxmtApPsX7IvYaSmWSHHbnruhxiSJj@UZCG5@ig7ci3UamiGyh/D/Mpj@IrJ7KP4fK1DqLe0KIMLOXzpZryqFpoSPf0REEtvgW3S1XoaeR9R6tXW1cDxHg8CDS38zolOpmgh4oF0fR36uom/E8tEAW3ItUywplzV7mhojhi4MipCH5Kv3vrGXOLu9tSOxk84PCY6xrMSuJmOG3Fj5/z5iRLf39KEZHz5/3FWgI5zrY0c7zkX4atRE9pz0PvyrNpUH2/i7OcXO3UyNXdZ5wvqntm1umZX69rUOXzfQ90DONLlZ1MeqwSUv6s617h7kOTR2JrrOkHqGpZhfA11UR5y6WhZ8ydmt3DnfwuSfhPekdqACPH44owdDNlEJBq7H@o7XW0AI5NjuVZfS5DvIVADJ3v47/y55t2DsMPOdM1u8a0PoI5D1nrD0NitDkW4coLrzvMnkhqGpeIG1UeUd6CM9/yaqammZX9x3qOjWm6/T4963xg49EMzugk6pzGvuttU0q9hBt3lu044y2odq9Hs6l8qUkNTXVO/TnlzONz7qF0qhDHVXGeJTQxOGjrQyh4lkQkqwfhjfOw@NP4FlnDm1n5jYNujLwuGyRV/f6qVrxCg46H8xeLsnGga8nFblbd96JFlCrGW@yA3kQKNynJCS4NWojw4AzSxg0xIL1pUfEDpmao3FSawjvYtU5diMwBN4umBDQ0QPm/y4iFBuCPkG1iFkZ1Bx4l@mXG7LdCp8GcuwloHD2vxlSTHsG4DE83Q9VVTPOaOyv6q42NLILlH10CSKbHWmdAGD85uGXrf4b8s0c7MxTK7eD8LNZpv6YrmaWltvkyBri9pdj3Lxm30oEIkmrbmNHHGG6Uvl4pc5JhWB6RwwmBjYA92bhVm9wvM000mR7jE232to@K2uj0dd9gZzuygB5intw58DeLXA9XRXw8sV5uLc3oLwdegfKV29ObORCt4CD3qij1Y/DHRCTBotiFuu7pDu5k9x/yOw9mMVuNnI6cn1f1TdY9PhAT0IrGplCV2mbf51HfgtD7Gq3PzmtQ6xUL8g4JOd2nCVDzn1nP@dovHZhFuB73@wBGP@bn38GxCcOa4d03hzq0OUjDxEYQu66qGO392OTB5CvqUGAnHzoe07Pe6YXXY@0KagfoFAg6V7gcYax3G5UPVhR5gzmFWyv8r1y1xbiLBlRrnIzCClmUJ3dTdx@dhXFcFO8h7YoW4qoVnb1J7@Jt89q0YEifzqbL3qMSHIX3UNMCy@RLU4bsvQGgbXx5avrDsAkOlZQ7cBJ5XfGyIyD86RJTYsJAP8ACLvN56dRr1WKHTbfK9jF/QxBwNLLqBY4zGrgcX@@dwmI7ntB8WsrMpPNNgU2urA8M9whW9r0lX6/cNnNkAmb5pzTNhDkcwxHyTHQSjxKC3qTVxJfCryrBvvQL1DMatPkjV3pGGS/dTguThxJh0z2qqBtCsNZsd3@dzREdY/cNOTlzs0YUw3RYnLZ2kd5w5RPuZ6eiTdxSGhfBA1gCVKteyk4zgIhE1FotGJZ4IF6Y6JoB5UHSgFA@b8bOqDgPedQlWb7Pzc7Z0NyylS8o9qzC5JLPLS44VP3T0aWvYp9OgRzz5@ZJ6WVkKJxLhpfCFWWLpsA@uGSCe54KrE7BtnR68vGMSMFPlu9bR7dW4zA/TOV06qAqmSAtMmlOTZhrRPOJHwvh5wxPc@fI3f9kS53c7GlS2p4OKBATB4@tWT@tat095viJ3YDwVz/8iDhhNDX4aLbFRYyDmwfbhx3atW3a6fVIQhwHFWXnwHHLd2C8Fb1ycfcOt/C5vPF4af1u2yNhP5VUKhMqgZ4K12XK7TpId67RLf2CPN8WCC8FM10aTuxVnu6yl4YYDOnxBs0yGZV3TKSosyd/8JT8CSUcwxNZ4L3s6@hzIEU9aKHTusNm0BlBqD8knzbYESASJDGPrAOdvGYpbCo/iwQQ6mwkcmfBOJlI2/HjiRu2YJbZYGK8BwANPZb0dWaodPX9znr6s/MB6Ke0//SwVvROEk79LFPOOHGceSPkeGSsYnYPocWyYyUtDmWfon0/RhbC45e0BJFI5k@ERFY/HLKsveg2dLqfD1D43iltOIuimdvaOKPboYDoxrHZLRxRp97aJogJPfJsOdDDwRgk173WVpciATzMmjl2WgwzxmKcKLn6UnU5s4HE7TLI0ZJ9ZF5ks0cRTBODjhDTwhGevsu5tQcsGNwqmNrXGgDbH3GSSmWyFqrNUr6xVyWVrLQtPWp9/fzHMpBMXw9Wty5TjEfXiYvhdOvMWqG7ZkOpJCnve1v7m3VKymv782VFHTJbvw2W@sRHExNLd4e7h1vFJ7eT0GFrh3hM/25bdU8eyBrmIzgV0LYPOsANdbF1zvkH@@D4Aj0TYksrW8HaWaFQKbkwnUEFrOSEvcWdANE2k/kLyeekdLRA/CyBkWltnHkftwiCFbQjMhlTDyg/6eBKfibTiNDFxmY4yHjuQTxjcPjpHlhKpZFYBYiWAWF9JKvZwZZ/ysK@h2BexPE62p3NBkGJ@fud@PK/iXBLc/1bq3YeB8jevN8fyeL0J5pF6A6gf6qXZru3unR5tTSYDHqMnSd1KMSdOZHDhjD2Nz1B6x6fpWJxIiFO0FZnJlIB7xWBGV@80NPdWg2oJ4djs8cTEoVR@WRozJlCmgvcXXZY5LSIRKgHqIGWs1tSBkbY@DBTRG6MD6O54FX0hsC37qL2CJ2WBOUR3ySTx41UDsQpyeV3vkIS4kNdhJ6j@xL0eh1XDMRqsP0r1wFDljzoOg//AqOS5MpdsyMRwplyyBMvA19DMDlTYg42W@RjFljgh5CVedtkvL95jAmVqXak0U0J7F8WZGBilDbWPlyYI6H3L1Urs48Cio32eMPH1i1u0w1V@ZQ81bVPF2tCRQdPFCxC8cYvw7W4fV1A746oZyfcgzw1MHKgAKHCBDij5Nt511CZZz6/i4CS3xK0P3lBJU@eOOOXtawkOu9EdmlrHRmijjmOApMTaiIrj7VV0qJPVDAd0khYM3/yuJ1JOkrTBnu@yT5hMDgFPJn2VMc5kCWGdyuwtADCU3jZhWP3AEy8RHGF2AjjDa4uJBFCuo5vebUslXAGgqdESc@0B7lOphmeSeEUokSvRdXtGAHDOfSgXWurHf/pn/A6UCxfcPxfuYXodfH8ofG1w/xMvRlHA9898XwZ8f8R936ewyWYvfhDZC8PwwdMIwJfP5Jk6oUzwrpyiuvitjS39ZveQObRMgW3ZU4eBZkIJgzynm0AvvQdMcUNtjOA8h3ETjvFEzt8AiwBfAX@geoMaDeWn2ZcRPP5fSqWw4DiXkqQt7NqQr1HQbQAfB3gLDihhqXwuv6KkoJCJGw8hHcnt4CZqjjAaLYFMlG70fuVDo4lnY5jsgBGnVfJlzhupJfX7rPzBL@gSwErcUDhnkAaP0/gpIK4qkkWW1JgSxaQ4kIWVMMq0lsVZDbTBCDkAJIrBpnfyENRNS5AK@NjUhi5pTCPPAGrgbWc4t6rxu5A8RAlAxHHjXS3T3XG8LRqPkQQ6aDLYDPIZgh0jWEmex6zn37ML98K8FHf2MGC8X85hXRPc/3jORT6cs/CQ8uwNMpHp@1@wNuzZsWnh9vltKC2LZFKZbErJRwMcKgtUUF7s6p8BJXRuEBZNTb@y@k5tY2v3xcHh8cxNKAQZngYLs3B1LXaRSMbPL31H2C/3JFHXt1PHr9a3PVIGSzXeYYIQ420m08Wcl9t0SR/I/YzvR5/NmyJmMlLSX4uY1nQT27QLaxb7ODYVANzg22Fnco1E7@7PL9eqF2ZoJvvP826HCiWXkbnAdeHQ3VDh6WJiEXe9XfYneOukk/SOW2Xk8d1n/iEx7h8HP3yXiX@H5fhCE28/v0QHgseHhpMP7PSHuidTPCu6zYMXzCsvyBqvqAoWdZxhU5rZJRQsDRN1mb1uU5x484l0wOeQvMsSHQ7pkHDms0x0q5BPMx/uxMOIXX98xYi4W6MLpTP0hnQrjoF75wX9I@BJp2/obiQqmQJi@uTgLKTz6E0dPphaOR8y/wicgzrjMElzzBG6COv2UuIXnTDvPpIYXWlyOAC6HVp9Np5F29Q81xHoVGxzwOccNfZi0AO4Nj2ONBwtNNCyEpAY6Bn2inKOl3gISiR7rVxkGE12tWFL78CIE4nGQTR9pyjjy1BUvM0D9KrGvBrgtFS/q0IdsGmya3iXyDC6ViTvuIJ8tpPdzg82LyVAhkkb0RKfuQifmt69VdjwJRaO@5RpROPhJOOWlLiSinY60ERUkm10cV8oTX202zqpbMErBvhg3tbtXhJrBcMMZ6HnuCs8yDXfdC9NgDLquZrUzZY2jOAVAKVLpBOEh2/PbsJReYbF6XIccRVKa/qWHE8Wqq4QSuMbZqbkXbHoy7lJ0VAs4jUCeJgSjBLI8di198AJKkKk3VP7LDKga4YclmTkjVxEzLjj2lGWqOJwfctMFovRnAY8KAJsFgRtk0un@xwieCtfJFWBRsJQx2zh45PeZ@dKMnkJbsokypZwPnMDtCmcCYxKYKNCkhKhBf0C/kpYIn6HalLcpbpE2Up00wdAzY0mOYXLCSBfgBZUa1Z9ErghYSxgOFWLxZJojUlpX2TAF2tzBCKgnSPFPRsB6CtOwwHVUEYD1IattXSQl89eaqapAYGAZ3p4Zaw6ACazo3HvNuP4@LZByiHEi7gjjtdBQSdvIdwK3xk4S7@UKtPUWPke1JoPF6jXtIVmM0r9t6lkqnwXWTIqoxTomtFqZKlbUWLZ5VhsyVyOLJmobT15gjNq90ugzNWTYKAOASixZETLwM@g/FWWzPKSuhZZalUyy5QCvGAi30GCH5xU8m5JvU8tPQFlKQ4hNhc6kSWHLghKJ5PKPZQPe8hSKg48c4c33dAdxZj9kh6LYRmSS3UswA@pi@MYDZsXxymavCsLWyDV6YnuNqWK@S0xc7cyJ6AILvkDVg4HLLFVsu4Bj@8gzM6Le0D94xm/xA3ljPbBaE7Q@JInY75esAg5jTJXCJkIv6EJCDiMABHRG1ejURAmv/51SMkzJj/NZyNW7GkuXY6FcwqY6WBfh56BHp5alm357mIzccO0dib/MXGutpMfLw@vDw/fRi8irMjCoY0DWVmRv8drpL/us8oyD3zYT/@EQsspKZRaVp6splIfPnwAiwM@59VkFcQH/0TPE@HL88gqY9XV1eV4vrAcfxauB4oVjWQy0WOm6yl2ofedVgu@VpcuFI@E@OfpU8oLzH/4ZzxM5C8cngdBRGjoG@Fu1FyIXayq6nJsJfPMLCcz6czf/LvF@/jdYX3tb36vl9IW8XGAj5/fv0L3sZL7bnHxu/X1lZU4EJK7D98fvqvVaiub8dzhee7pSiK9uPYf/4/FxUxmLZNavHQc5TJ8fv1WzqRX5OTf/EX48PB13XGAEEX8ZJkCTvwtwFdhuRy7Zp/gc91m@E/uT62AW0V3o/0Jb2UCe6VCwiYczmXDx9@H5zfbIlOqT1f/8x8ffAy5oWomdWbD0w19DOULIe4EB/iynu8mVA2tIVj@PjRKVSoVcK7@5/8V0ldfAB6MGa3BTzXn4cqPQtVEhZJ8DlXz4FAyGcj3//rZz6RQdRj6FFIUJTSivzq64VN4ojxh6EjJqwXZsp7hlef4GQY@41qkFCVz4bVnoLmxaf3gLuCGdmVWIMxvd5@rmOAGcnwtXBV@tvDzt//73/7p3/4x/f0pff8D3qSdX3z2YZMxDUZg/JRKz2baYW/Kf5RMwCfp944QehOiZqFCJV7npfJZOBRwTNHB/2WCJL7/G@GkkHcdLMqhy4nGuAgphZWDZ8Ov/rBxoT3ahsYk9TNn02FeY/ge5skC9i1wUuiHSuXIxb9XDfw7dPCPDX/KB9nhKXwW4Y/@4eN78XeRQkQwgcx@Fn8D6SuFzkPnl5c7Jv597NKfjX@Nj/i39wn/Prr4d9LEv6OP@HfyCf/YTG2k0NraWigWOwKVUTDt13xO4ZtM1oXPZ96QFPqtftjKQf7gmQR94jKWuL8/T34/jJXL4h@UqbLvww93QbEu7xOJte@rsdg5Fe@8Ksq5lrisQll5kenn@zVAHFs7X1tL1qvVauLy@@r52mQike7Zsxh21GeQsHp5fi6F7rAtKlJoGZ9NRwplZDlFns8o02GQLkoh1G@LXM0t8gB6CwT6pNCHuw@R2NPY07SRvkkr18r1K@tg/H9wMIQIfZi@sux0N91VWiAkWVo7TY/So2G6Zx0oLXBq8JfugVNPt4fpTtpMm4oyGk6gevi/d2C5rw4swGZBSneYdhFxug3PzsHBK8DXhryv4E9Pp9NDKOQwfQP/aQNFNl0wR8/v69E7@Hy4/3BxfyGdM/mDBppBUgkn0@FkPhzWL3P5/kc5Hq5fnIcvy6GUc3GR4joTy6yU6YbB@/t6fWt/s15PIRetLcWexRLP4FOpxtbE42moWn56UUpg63HuS9ZDqbWnF9VsAt35GDRRBsLWUrFv/IxRwrO6eCGBGXh2ht@z25tb7iIHuS4w/KzOo@GboiDyUhB8bm5T8xFMOBgooL@j/9bBf1n/r05Z5Pwyyljk7n4tQp8o/kWjd/d39@K3Go1EhCeyBn8YAH5McndfRScB3YHrPBK9jN7f8zD4jUTXOMIq5rFWpcRjQOivIZ7rRbjMGBhMEbHWdnExTKej5QaE@LPu6mdatomWaUPLUgOX2sBIUJajBJJbKZdXhHu1UC4XhFvJ58vlZR8qDR7hBCDNUZtl5PRyqB/FMnD@j6RxroXucQ1HWlobL/R/2u@DwacU058/@0H1eku363UMz37@fAFdKYz7WSrFHISkC58/Q0cMR8EY3LfESmoRTDsllRmj76qO6rp2BMz9@EUYt9k5F@EoxmfSaQTG9Cy3tpZfqVbzK@DOF6LRsrzEN8NEOrGiEr1fSsm8GmCmhUMiSimsRin0PozxLLTGnlaBwx38sLv7EFGbreSikcZIi/oBSrHIQ9hKPlKIFcVfZTHKUtVlJv7Oz7OxleXV5WeXl@PRC8VE@U6tKPeVO7WEUwf35aa4RBU3tapPnmSLQJZCunwh1eubtZNaHd9GgcvSIIYZBpLAkXDJsW@Hz2meJ1e8PMeKXF6Ew6XyM96uhRwLhcsCLhEG0cUKRapvCIxJvY272YeAFfFKoZKynMkupnLD7/JbaTCClvFzfn5eyBRiyyDXlovFy8tLCl2jFOe9YfuSLtKqJM6VfO4ygarL1bC9HOozZTUbWpb6tLloNc1auD5r45zZIgRCk7IGLqU7mmF4d9beWrbRutVb2qIUOtyrbWydxDNrgDKzXduIZ45P10MKenNjP0Vn0X@0Vds8OIUEh3tbteOt57tvtk4PIRxvuIRP71DVBlpdux0MbtFf1@izoTvq1ZXa79f78Bm2f/zlH/z4y//uxz//ox///A9@/PM//dUv/vQP4PuX8P0j/vyjf1vM4e@vfvHP/ucf//WfQ@B/gO@/h@@/@9Uv/sXP@Jf8fw3f/zMQ9tfiG4DjXwlw/eGvfvHHf/GrX/yTfwnffyW@/3L6@@Of/G/8/z@KP3T@@Y9/8tf4Izx/8Ec//v4f//j7v/fj7//8x9//h9BEf/9Xv8T/P/6rv//3v8T//@Xf/P1f/Q9//4f/Ezn@jDv@73/1b/nv3/3eH/zd7//zv/u9Xzzw@weP/v7iK8J/8TsI@fpyfg2er6nXt4b84ieV5zehxjgX4AHgun/847/4R8C3f8J9/z344N@P@rnv8WNiZM8lYuPAnzP2OQV6U/rZZx8UUP6PGArB7PMkNgpNe6G/@sU//wsMnoD9R0EMaWUWdgmB/dx@DrD/2i9YEPbnP/7yZz/@xT/88Zd/9uMv/xAlWWKlGK/FE8oXpoQAMPcVcAiY/xo4AFTWcHV8kS1KGXAsruEUhqTEPnwAki6Cq8LYspTLgi90eVnFz8V5qnqRuqjyzyX4k6kqhiRTFymMT6ZQc1eqlBKKEAN5rYDds8wnHGI4zwDfobRSBB9OQcRgmInxqBhErcdYpVKJScMKxBEoeDHNkFULaFyhbVEBvJiIp4nXC6C5suE6YYGUldgRqy9XhjxhDAOqhIFhgTDoSFYycqxQ2YQMK8NNhrgQeUz6AM8PlWqhMqwiuh@oCIAjtg5ZAlQFSzes/gD@CuEEeGm4@QMUpVCJxaoFCKlQVSm3eJ3yVHJUOap7jFG9MRwMXXg8fcbYd7JSkLmNB4RnAhp/Y2PopzTV8RTiL2LLojr07znpu4zpoVWHRB8exuOfYjClFwCAN5HAfVfwTSSwNM8geshRxShbeMQ4BqBcTEwV@QE0yMekGLVvjDyQP5Th6z5r1YAH0WF1lpaWwLVWlbPyAZgLzL4uOa5q47IE6UElJueLMgbjNhZt6ZAMiuXNZfhV4H9rkbaicnIsS0thHPPDzMsjEctaK1aISu9VjeqyTCWPEZwUGodzHZbWlkD5XGFRKUK3tUfJKtX6fXi@cjrr1hD0zLgsx5U8nz2OotEKke@sUqnyg7KyKsGT/AO8KF5cWQ7NgC8PS2JfRIJW7xJr1C/BCXpJXqpWxfoYU6Tq8dYJJDg5YEomnWSgnN6trGZWciu5TDafz61mlJV8cSWfK2RBnuXTuUxGKa6sFAvF1Xsq0jOQC/HSciO3Vv0HM5//5h/M@8wPxY9UfcuGSZa4l6rDRCKVoRJXlNxqeVSBclCQVCWNi6vho7sEbouULmgb1h3u@IFiSXcJZNMF@DBpQWILEAQfQIsrA0wsV@8elMW6Hb6Cg6/dyUoOGCEqXQAjcGxSf@ojYbs9AWHzROHOXH7sTKPzBI@E7UMW0Aom28Mtkq7FTiy@FW9da0pr4jBTVZJoneMcaHop4RX355fSWsqPnY9po8tfTLdhW6DG/nSYddW85lGbOj/G4kftqHjPlNPT3e4DEKf9Hh6w0ezfGYatXgMKiPOZHGAdfmzDsuYBrLLTwwdq@co/YooLhnTGFMCPdp/vnASeJ1u1jR0pz9YP9jenHjkBlGN7W9snvneVx3pJcz6Kd1t7e9Ne8UBTZJHlVuNxEI/wg884feiZXPreA1GSj9yuDmNTao0tNclGRIszB90e33Z6Uamqw7Y5ACava5X183LosloAKbOymlvNp4ur0F33B70BUoKdDgqsM7Dd0VvpFe4UKyr8xIPuSDtgs/Twonq85MCVbK0F9sutSYc5Gvi6qUGfPRgIDwxCp613upD7reUBSA1VZfD91g@k14If9/EAl@dBYTMxxhxwXBvT2ywtJWluK1Ms5ArFbKYQLxQLKzkw7XJxJRNXVgurxXRcSSsFJV/IFZV4YaWYXQFpCLG54qoUAqmht1MpEPaKLNNTN5t4mewa3sprJbtVKcRnBmCExfcohlQ/AJpDzhYu0pBOlnAXLNMrizK@qTSN7wEFhCprstD29kZ6e1uW19GDU3kbaVluoSdXSKdX12VZo5gNENgZWbZ4GogCMJd70un1DVkecAR4HlaWu@jZyqMeKss6ejZq29uYzxV6MpgewK55DPcYnmcVwEz0ZLOkyMryRx8dwNV4RitU0i30YJ4Ys81jNiBOlp975UmnAcMRh@MYdry61mqyvMs9tRrGvKCK53hRX6KnRh9ZtsEDPCjLHXB0bDC2ZbkBTuREWW6CqzlSIQwv7sWjk6aryvKIEwhJJMtDglab1zKoUSIcs9nZ2VG7bkvr8M/I5s8mFA1i9OFga7vx/Hmj02nYo9rW8yOMefFiR70aDexGpyGSNerwsSANxFz3RtMfKONuva4ac2NeQow5FVMf1TUsW139CGUSnw5m0qu/gJgXEDNvbYRjg08PQBv4We/Bc11tUIz3oRh6DhsNuYw86o76Gs6gYJeh3UTlYEhPbdpWGV2gd7PFcCQcH50rl/FPZYphPcYi0bt0@R5B2hF6CQlKRVBy7kbnw0r6ErRtpYyTO5HF3lMZhJxcWlSfRobozssl0LdX5GgJX@BitcMsnFCeDgpyflUuLcNTfipnwTmMpMNpxuAner56@VReRSTy06cJGcoCXgBRIaG8WkSExVUY@8v3QA8XhqLGwNXq9UjkVlOvo1FeJ/7SJ3Z2dha94zuodKqjW25HhvFhhZeG6dHyJyj8NKYWnhYdNF3L5vg6QIFPT9MlqiRkX6DsWSoVXUOJhDIEnh9odjrJSgn@vhOlkI8mccN13WrX6c0D7IM3hX12NuOa9aNaeIYHJ@jQpLfDhjRipySdoO5I71NkeAi9ga8golO0YJTw2zDohUEaaJJFSaoKZepEG7rJHQ13uzTLImxTddXk9sDECifxRUlu@S5xlring7l4bhGPw@otplaq4FJbLEJATI3eUhnq1WqlXulpvb47AluC1NmqnxgGMrbOOCQegfB2gdcr61C0dNnE2x809C4NQ0Op2oLSgGm2fjcolQD2vtypnGPiz/izlpCr8mUicf75ElTPSro8CqkVZ9CgWwJYugG6cb48hDBldaVsQIn52Y0l2sGllrusUWl8PyxfV2AQWWqzDMuvlClR5TyTLsYzCgwbMJxAAHxX42kIUS4XFyNGxLW2TKhJulTCCgEpyAtPNRrLLBuRlsXUtQQRBlgW@gNuoo/GDKZoSuyaQLqsr8e7EUBxpKkGTxtNsOxKtBykViRajixGK472sdyuRL4HLZc06c8Gzo8u1itprlMvOYPeeXoxr8TvEvXEvaE67pKymimdD5bOE1jo9OfOmvweyAX0updA/Q5O38IYWYYwj3f5qDoeF8dh/TKoOoYG1FWKmbIAkfqiB0VkFsE3afFtSZFweDUTDkfDZYBahGDqiNE76jdh6M3hJ9CHYVyGTlzMQLytuQNQAUG6zJSA2w15RQrdSy3d6bOVohS6k@7v7teqnob1ko1GaizheZ8w1omBBZmi5aZkPcQWyZVIVp@xWqXWOaqVBWhtg@y8lMQu@GG3RGrxWxe1YmvV7/nzApczIRuJE4dWfVNrsWrqQpJlOSR7qxGRQi7K7csfQnSXJdu4a2O/0y2z9ApppZaO6Yr588voD/u6cVfIJqpkeQBT3N@HYlA33M9QTRGlmge0jUAKmZZw4gS1C10cpFQuJ6MZqrH@cfH71e8L3786PTg92GbP0qVCqcDJcMEtw7gSVsJgdj4D9Ug/2pJC/c9WTvnBfFEOlfrh7Eo4O6HYXlTEOe8IMkHkHJdv4Ht5DgbmZRRclYryVFkt6Y5YXYmUnEFfs6NPlXymlEkr0ZBzj4dQM6sheir51dBliKNcWY2Cm9YFMkqomhLByiqmSnAfcG8u5BQ/hzLpghQqvPrwmTHv3b96hlyplCjs0v3aPfxX78/BsL4n@/qe/vEnBT/3HID@MYHnocf4MwE3hhnHX/6QWOP/a/SzccBLLuehIUIfoLM7zvf17@shKVQMg2EQxvfY889QmKyo5C6b9Kc5y/j3/Thg2XGcZd8H3mWoM8tVFQZqcSp1EX2dAYW4WMwX8iHp17Of1DJY2MsLNRbm10Xx4QQvi/QPOoUn3saFkyLLC4nN44ONl1snOJ5oJr5NlW0c7CcxCl/4OT6p1jQ01TZG4o2fI4TCYehk45BZYMVsHlKaMzqjSKE09yFyWdptlcRrceI3TElmcc0sl0qvpJQcUwql9Gopk2cqyCEH7yQQriVMyqhaG1Z/xM2YyEaUEi/UEAbj9nQwJh2txJ4f7lEKuq5geWFz69UBO9jfe5f0Qnn4yc7uMTs@2D45qx1tQT1ebR0zuXbMdo9ldrZ7snNwesJq@@8YRB/V9k92t44RQUpCGYZqFSeYb1OwNWfkpFDncsiwmAh2rOa15k6Gq3ZfTeHtp5PBJr4LRcM3CEyGD0ywyFtBm@W4tsAVGIbo1VbLlvBwpN5kC2iwLCxrNu4glrtpZ5XlBm8/pe3cImuu7IdXWTO9b2bXVpmRFn/MWOllj9ji4uKFKfsDQLAavskUDMJt9RA2LtPu@62FSH6FLYOhlFmJjmP2Dw4X0p5v4ezoZEHx4442FzK@Z3d7Iet7tsC34vu2zzYXcr5vvfZyIT9Otr@xsOr7Nrc2Fgq@D5h0oTjGub@5oKQlj1g3oPQs0PveItu7e1tsGYCi5YlYnJFCx1QwECIyMB1@UwXZiMvLt10rThp3YzQF3dK@BO2BT0AtoKZ0jnS9jLNlqw8/oIMBMCSTfBVYtTvNuMCKNwXByCLdSQtYoQWsEMAv4BlphGOLFZaJMoheaPPl@wi/OS7O5FOHTkJ@57A11GWrwAxxunqITsRCCk28@FFauBcoI22atWvTNl8CBbuCybYcjeIxuv3TvT2eGYwNtmVHZIJk5JHn4LT6gA2qCL9YdQjljcObhdoCabUgtAp8OaV0P9Ga0nRrIimgngsLTUAwSd0b1Ygz1KriuDaMeNHDt@cDMESDOw0ufn4wEmliXTua26QCRZGYWwfbvIa4ulxhk60cZZgpUYqi@cb/z5@Z57twJ732pNcMc9wCOS8Wx8dLWkHYKIYteAc3CYIOqVPKBeSYWAxSQ3UoLlCvBSA6fPmZdq@UVcgoHWZPnlA51sBXDFMWmC5GObIEgiACQTAiHyLzi7ZIxY0upJZx3wd/szsSEccRfhlpY@TfxwGSdbqgU63q90K/ORdMMOHKUwJZRLVb2Nbgzmbq4EfxCJwcZw3oJnHmRSp5jET7KM60OGtD8JRMresmcK5mj2WixwrQGan19zd5C/HLZyicB1CNQe6VqMFAWDzB7kuMvrDQsMGQLXtQIA8JCvgWmSaChOBwj6c72qRky7y/IFti6q9Jubtd8viIpwZ2EJxGZMX7AjiviOpSYHUMNINfIMP@WwH0nCU5slhMQPhcJsC2JuESCQ537/HlFyqxNV2LxW@uBYrlB2ux9ZXV@M1qAcPamEWgFiDiI4A3BtD0M9mamXkoYCwkFFSbn4YCBtAxL0Efn0DwFelhyB2nT3x7ehikS9NdGfottCCXCjzJpLc56W1NerH7QojKwCbIrLDPrIEuJQ8uPDfOCuBocVk5mbA96aXpkwrTvDRtXwLzHIDnUFRyMGTAWWGMEiTp4IsT1B6@vqfCatv13f2tk8lYxJd06qLgXdcyDcojOgkmCoTxTgQ9Ub9EkTYSgeubkUOeR5zoWT8@OdqqvYpD@aJsbdwDpnUA@BE9YaIG914OEGpqTRiPW3EWOa6x5Sh7giWLMzFZgJ6vzsKwHA1QPZhja9DPUFZpDuL7J3tSCHukNCcrOcIiUfb54gKG1PQqU3r9z9le1lzNttgou4rKLsfj6yBCynsCZp93Ta5sIGSL35JXmpvZVTrNVuwsc7UuaNzDtD2Ln@p1j2MbDYve6da@RUaZU2Z4mBhli7gLBMbFSdXmcS2SxkbkAwzFbgxhOJzTfFuM9HNkT4r1FCxelpb2rWX5kkY7WZYEL8saZTpbhl@LaUowl6SpE8x0pYrVd/sqHvIVkQd9nE85xCBbkvg8S@BmrYiFr0xxoyW6EQVlSr2O12PW6xFHM9r4dvaB3YQhH9VlR4DhB2OTPJI6EjomIwV5UH@ajGjpeCgXLx@EUWcKIb0kvkL3@EUoR0nyS@a4Wp9KFSgGzpPhu4SDGYKBPeGHZsXDcoESR0tCK95WsT94yM4nLkPiOAZONz4nGMTzbKjPpnPifLaZE4d33s1L4h3inhN3NejNKwEIhgdixDHMOTGmdTAvAb9LaBxxeR4g4HmQwJeXkej8pod@NdnigcugiP4n9kATNxvtHgRYEJRLwYGBtg5tasC0TR0vop9G5B8Eh5SRYTRwJt1nq@iYk1SnqevT6D1MAhEdqqS71tmw1OwC1u@UTCEaDyAMYGzxyzgfwskCSKGEc5CE2DHxvjcD6viokQWn8Y7TJ/FKBbMF5t04gdV/BB5jx7DY@B7wAt6G5cf4zDyny43RlWYZh8Jx0h2bX5m4N@whaK8SSjRI0N80@8S3Zp8I5I998idlXWHnk@W4jAX8JQgY19Hr4D8pI6/Uk7lFv6nGQa7RtOsH2Bfvdwlkw@91mMzWRyMkkM9TXlUIPQZ8pZBAXEFE3yBfqPnEqfN5qcfjz3KFJRQ/DZd4495Ak@uBwkt4I0W9jle51ut0h1@9jjNL9brMc6CBFwe84KArOhuPS4KWWrcoNiInVDkuJxK1443d3YRuynF@t3dFdlzL1up4FZccx9XXikwCq44wXc3oV2SxEU51GKWWH86jFsgDKvjlTAiI57JrUibjO1q/nF0zWCXrK6pkTWU2vjfyK3I7otzwiPxjOdn8AjYvow26IwwvXbM1HQUNv7VcvIgbL9OYuMMBp/RFEXi@Ds30OXhzBi8SPeoYJtoar6Cg151XGM32yd6dMvLMFTCit@NUDyIYcyrnPvmQ3m3E6H6xlib0LJoeSsrjuyVFwZKipgF@9xQ0fiXHeECbvGdGlDfuzU06OI05VdSxYLH6WPlzGa@hgQY4tPrw619FA27/Mhpw43U0GOSJOnDjXTSYoi0c4loacNHFNPAE9pbH92D21KHeG@DETfCyA6HJjYuFQz7WhEZ9ipyUfpyiCJE08ELhiMAbjcklGaru0CU40xfhIPy8u3Cil9KskKWbm7GYAdVhHtK5t@tE47@FRgooYiiaHVEaSBuXmcyVEEqrlC7B@AzwjidiUH2eCrP4rCcigprE/fTj8Spwl05lwrxAioDxwAszTsBnmYLvECTlPlryVZBxiwWhuOI2p9y4kfXBggcxeIpaVHrEkvr/jZ0UbJL/Qk2l/@@NohnT53dsyjxiwnyztfJbNAv@q0L/XxX6n6DQ/9a0@QdU8mmUsz1@Sl3/ohr@7eoXybwRDBt25wan3jI/RQ/7LSkCq9@kB3ilPlce0wW@PD57aDLBYf0njtLSr1MnrfzZtlWr1U56in30vNapdWtHeG3Renovdna1sr55u/58vVXb3Oy86Gzsa68LtZW9/su3hXfP258@aqC97xy8eP/J6De70tuj/u2Zdnib1QpObTD4uLszcnfWT3sbx7l3q7fpLSPXXtc@bhrO5quTty9PnueOY7cfXxy@@NRL95zDdlot9rI7r/JvNkZnppS70U9b23v6Qe@4tXWa6e1t6u@2YxvpvePiayW9t3X7PrtxG8ulU7v9lwfPj06vGlvvjaPdvXetjY@Wmv94fdvfTbWK7Y2rozfSQfa1svPx4KCzlSk@30ndbrb7rXRmx7BzV2@PDtdP3@10X6pbve3cafHt1egw3339@sbdj3VWzvKDV85KzKy9fp15aT6/udk6khqqdWJntTPrtdK/vT20ir1V7eX@Tqf32lbM1EHuTey4d3K7ubVufFwdZk/fnb2@XTl@N3j1@sX7g7R@fNzYUvP9RitzfHWyIjV72d3YzenWaUF93jp73bvZ3cm920y96mr7tdahcf28s/PeOj7c261lnYGp7G3cGO@ed69eXW9u7BrW4bVh1lZSOeOk9e7gQDp9oTc2tZ23zovaVfddKrd@vfIu1uo/P7n61L1@sX58elDIDA9HaWvDOWrstIebR/lMIdU0Ph59aluvlNPXsfzN1YuM/q72yZWyn0a54p7xTuuZL2LNzvvhRyMVO1WUjfe7n969O965sRs18/Tjm@2jK/tVyzxwDtJHL16@ahjXBfeq/948Plaa6efa9atYWpWGpzsOtJF2ouZWT3p7r/vDTevj0e57J/8pdnN2ndU2r4/e1D4epRu3Zv@tae/pvY1060CtvbHcrcHwebN4c3q9Y@x9PHDeSa@2lFxu22o76@03K8W3qeex9vXzt@vK8TC9bx61V/L2/pvXZ7q@1X17@umomdt@0y/0XLPz@tNpbyu2tTfsftIK6YZx/O7alE5zx0eHmVvzpd5zt3eOXuXdg/Tem8PWzkipvdaUW3N1Y5TbHNr57NnmW/vd9Y7ZT73TPw4O09pNrPWu76681hvt5hu92XspHb/onu4fvrndzeXt5z1TXz8spPf3djb2O62Vl6PdV4OtvcZV6/nuW@1t/yR/ndlaP8tvvj3OuifXL91i86aXPSzEToye2zmNSS8G3cHq4Zn98c3w/Uqt19CyR8Y7a7Sq9DZe9DPDN7Wtg0@d68O@ta9sZ0ap0z3r2kh/Orn9tOPka6NYYXjq9iz3RBnmlNdS9vZT333Rf/H6@GD9xcH7F@qKrp@pV8dvWunsaSGld@3sbj7/XNnabvc@9oqa8mnzVVbN9roxZ@861dponb45uzauei97V02pUHSa67vvB6q11cgo6Xfr7a2ctre@d6Jop52Xxyub@@nDt63D04/Dk9bG28HpmwM9vXX1orjXWXl79Kb4cvX9iXOinllvX9r70rCQtRwlX8zdZo@LhYOufZw9uyq6719e5deNs4byYjfT07Z1@21hVLjuf@redm6PtXSj83zzo3rU3gJJenqYVnOD6/3hsZR9c9K7We2vx95dN1@@NRWjcKavpk4@XhWvu92Xt5vNlbPap49q7vmVVjzeTjWM7dzz2NHG68OrzubZp8JKK72@90Z9O9zquu@k1zv65lXx7PpgOFJebx@PerW0aeRujs9yNyfW@vHZznGh@6phtxs7V12QDb3R6dXt4GZHW@0Obwsvu1dv1PTe28KG6awcpqUX2m6vdXTy8m0t1s5oRffm4N1@/6xwNsy9KlhnReugoL@stZ8PXx@0t9Krff3sZHi61U2tb@i9AsiUQ@PU3jh4vfP@7EU/LWXM/PqnDSu3@jF2M3yXP0sdxvYG75onmd6Zbe@81e3ttzeHb18e13Zju43R88Nr9eDdVu54f2PDeRHb1vPaaCd769Q2skbbkpze@nB/aPeL2ffXex0YCaxWsfX8JHtmOrVa@3a3cLxVqz13Grsv1OHweXsVxgj8bJ29sSrSr/mVdBK/jY4/VH73hdRzOg1rCPKSH6yT6NSURKemJH5OirZI8@3Hv04tSyfBAwP0Blw@wTNogLLGWhYqD0m2698bi6@NiLOeBcl1dDWtPj0RrTgX0UKDz4Bfmq/Co3v0/j5t2DcsHd/Ig28HQJvUHr9qKykdmKw3QnvT1Xr8GIOOL9UR17zSCwX4u4vomklpodlk3lsOk3SJqf/Oww@gQPTNToJure2wRKLZNtSOAw6jRa4P0rF/qzrmYOgqTn5gFspeXVXSObE1ld5MhoU7wXcB7T9nhsVfV@BZHCooEyO6@wMnqej@Dw3fhOboN5oxovdPaK2kxHd8ftUuyGAYbu@eDKOrNqf2hoK6odlTG0D7PKG30ppafobXsjxbToklVlSG6qrd0F18z26dH32o8xy9PW/9yb2HdKRWLNByxQg1G7qkNi6OBw3RN5UKKUbbzJt0EIQjQNUQVVRvt@Hycp9Q0r4rxj0BzMv9h3Hrvc5vC/UE7pauTeC1gFYDoBUtSM@s2X/n0CZHH6gs8cX6rbe7J3XxkhK@xXDi0NEDOy4DVC57vn6Z1yBQflHy2W2ZuMMAio/TjvyOZ6jqjcV5WaZ9j7g9ElobLezxbkt6jzwWHbH1aTfK@col30GYpq17HsH9NE84JzwJlOrJmKALYkOFzwNfmY5v0OQgs/VFxG1b0wiAdnN6R0OmNvv9lnnvgZZpGKp5ja4y3yoL9oLdDDQWvX4hUA@cyvLrIvZPko2A9Yak/jbYcUFl228WAhAbYr1mPjWxO9N@e0zDW9jPGufHMA/f6jIMqxkZRy97W2543aJeThx@KqsDnEls485ayx7xjHB6JlIuAwju0yGZoJnebtVArStjaiA62tQTKAXwbdkLwvP72riccfZ4aXlWi8QOtANoflH5ZiCEOveLdcmzelgWAr2jwcpMJB0Tx9tCBM7UMnOtPhChLTgOhjHiEb47dYYqfKeXz0WM0@k8fQn/7GnQU@Ibd7FDaTjtiSIkit0YLfSpwvmFRtCq33UwqzHrUUPhDm5sQp14kelg4WM402OxiXYKID/XkW4KixG1I3NiQQz5NRKkF7QnGNoTB63Bt@KyNt/BxWktTZFoDTL6/NnvMOD1ufHQO@cILOG/1RsZnHMm78uCoGXP73VC300xY6L4UvV@di89nfAEA9y67etDzYiAwKzjy1f6DILElqV@nzsIwt@@BMHY2FR2Ia8WFyOQ6pzgUoVL9oRFlLW1yGoiQkHfFaJRvzOK5JlA8kBiENLVKotkliNZL/EKJgaU2UkEK/MRZDiCleWI4iHICARKDjBwFYOQfMcKnGsnERcCiH28l5Mw@AqXObkvZ2LK5dpaAfd4BgKnEmfmF305G8tAYo56ITYZw9HyiED45WSNAHk2ExhHAihWYllAwbOOTUaMc52K8DMN5rlyOXdw@q0pL945DW/woeT4JknNPi9gfZFT@ab0PgN337VFIL7Nq0/v9BqHcZZeRjYHHYG6JOTW1fDQVJy/000MWkC/8tSoGDgcQRAoBogIHh49zq4eG@sa3z7YIXCbJvh4neNMibMCmCEgUUBiFCAxiBCigd6pN3t9Hw6G4kKU7/jmAxhlso8rznh@ANoJ1X4vJxJjnHy4wg34xDu1aAzh9I1Agvre7jo@3mwd4Y7Z3f3n0IQLWI84G/961VzkGP0qbqgmf8@H7upQBJBt3KARdeVNNZk/Bnr5C2wecgE/jZ0npNohBOOJhXZIfKG7dd0S2DgpPT7SXKIjvXbKByhEy2BnsFuNqQaSY8Rfl1vgb6eiQ2@UmkgFDj@hKCBSCGl2clTbP94@OHpFlDus1/YOd2qIGQzMpmq3GL0/BTuIaWoGH1R9eko4/HbwhdFYJ7XhveyDv0obYfmL@DjxALBOMXUKnS4R1pcz/Qw8D56XgCSKDw1KRb2l9efgxr2rPpiojDMHIW9FXmoxFIoyzRsJacCbHQk9OVpFSUe0tDTHDLvA2PQ@GdXk8iTl4VsHK5Nexkc9F/WoDvGLzd8@ls3QK4mRj5xBH1eHtZYcJL/abGoOXSwwpj6g1Iw2ZSIkS4BQEDK/9mP5wc@m@GOvwEFvZKRBN@3rvWM1d1JZBO2R0@4n6bgBBYlj8XSkO0@tJLVI5MzfkDyhOuqTKuNDmfHcrnhuV5AbF7jsaloh0y/PryYUsXnk0T3yXHHd2NPMuHribyWnlmtDp3e6eN0PzYVwqUMNhs1EV11YowlZ98RrsideLx73xPnK3eNKmSDspEYmBpzx@CkM5lYLyBaZmdugkytkfQ1sbH/uMbVb9NBIyQ86eSYGwROn1EGd9uA88YlnqB7kDMQE0pBOy5yL7C5pUPHxRQRClvDKEw3oGnQKU8wK6CZIi/HhNFFXUiUtRxiKgUAUq2IUtlteJyfI8WBmt6YPdCEQhvIDh@NTCfwYH8@ogE56m2OFUCOHjHVWiuC6aiIBCaJ8XoN0GhC3WAcqnu7Or0Zhthqicp5OpvMTMCjqhFvhogBBP4PdA6Fe5uW59Q7UwzsMh4mjgYqly@IEhXei9/SQZZVsNnD89@Bsn@Xz49PBeFcYW8mkx0eO8dYwli9KP2mebDyfwPkRO45oUGQr5Bk03UEX1AwDOjF/tHQc@rFs3Cwe8seo7CtXy9yCdYQ4FkODw3r4nviGhu9Dx/ValylDJSktgFCkOWDxoklv8AbAzkC1VdPV@BlLFORiZRczpISow2o21AtfEE/voQeJj69Jh2HB1vgEMIS0rCZtkkQclA5aetCj3UhxVBhuNBuvAdBdcdB/gWSOYAcuGqqcCbxATzhUPd7gJBQigXo0TrJwMtKwjNTjUy/ClSF15WQvTaU82VNoSPPeWYsFIPIKViEac7e0IAg8M8yQPb4sXtzldUkfeCz6500Nzg4y3Dj17HCBho8xs5a/fjlnMoa4qxkcg4ZiExOhojpdRr0zcCQBvCNQTW8eggPRY3hJwxPh4tYoUhDfYq/zuXBGMoK0CBqlaEixketwl464RY6iF/y3dhM/V6D3RcXOgJE4MOcfjxQQyPJRDiHORk5DYP/kEMMgDigF76jLqfH@gyHi8M@7ofgmDvGscHRHhV2ACLhdS2oXLz8/kza/FqKPUqb8SNp0SSkqGujL88F4lQUY1i4ABoUieeRVygM7PRyfe/MAqfQ0IfVY4Sdy@9rCi@xmgCYo8ZVF9wlxL@bq5iGFxD3rRuOLVGJbjVAzA@3DlSRoRMEIxLPU78VUhaCBJxV46RqBFFxn9tJ4koRixKHfWZEjoHzHcsY7DuwJdH@ac3yud15FOSd7VfWqSS1Ib8429D4NjZN1Fd0iWNeEMlvZ1UBlvVPGE5UVibx6zt7vYIKjbVi3/P4FHFBkcXJZ/q4VZ9@1cDFEhATHKI8a8@Tf5FnnQIf8vjLukX79/LLSoVnfw/uqWDtE0R7kd0yHeNNeJ8dXJ9MQoCC4ZZa9zfU81cKCUGdA6ZlIl4mKaWefnT0U7TbIa9qqj7fD7mU8TGOOISwV9gPHQ0PQJ82eAPbAPpOcxwJEfVh8fXwQNsBFQjJPdFKPOzAiFhPjWWViNnh8gPpBRgxiEbIzcET50fQkU2ZLMcI4PkzOx@ElEcP9uP@XgwUZPVgQJAetEYmxzl8z4lci3P@mK6Nj3a0vNDfQu/oZ@PkoFDGhv@XSnh4Q6Y/1Bd864PZAUDcQiranDOLEFijwYBvzo9FxBrk/CD@@YeQjX@DDo3mQkm4ACSajqyaCAomXMBMwi/oBI2a2mNQ6RNE@b5PJclND0kSIj51X40n/HJGlMglcBuTOmDJTqwl0jA4502xcmV/@QaosXuxNdmrw9g9s@GWsPC5Zju2sPh4O9nY7EAq91zc0fnJH2avXDnb9q62YeNe85lgY5CQtu5O61a/1FAeUjsW1VQltgP0cL6niMfWtUxjK8MIpN8mONb5ZAfVeVMs@kDmpDaIfMBHegGUCcLsNGq/Z1PDlIe4t7h8QCJxksLAQrTqgh1smG1lWY1x6VZzM4QWIU9kdKHwHCDNoJKEAqabqOtpIS2HCVMOAn56KdzSnwCRPYQ1TB6a2B6mPoUtoySv1RpU2AwWjk9NTudI1dFIC544oxsVXbdPuEZxDcOl18w0L2sbfnyqMBLrb0TKNETPxCoCOiu98Z/T2X8gKOe8Wqkk7bsWiDm150MiOWEkX8yTsHTHCUTocv5NJiMtFJf6a2BKe73AsZBdbo72plHxiT8vUngzeMSc3UXA7fzKsiZdzfXmfhr/FI5UKpLXMr9n3MW@PB93/BWR/aOdHKoXTo31DHTH5VqXbsdnGymo6X0JbS@@YxIbYW/ASnYDGrg37@LJV3BiA47iX1tBuNINlsRnf6M4AAI/dAVRJCvVttdNTPcBItsQwm8AdXWRfT5zoH0dZljEZ0sZzE2xsUePJNMaUMTY6wSVGFSSmCBbjghYFqQU/T3HLs2X1WQkcLa0x6NBggOeyvBR4OkqNNzCBGq1GGtGn8CzBE4qORVqGfoydv@LfX4X7iSydnUM3v2TeAoVclqgW0PUrvPRlLz2OHAgWWNGBAZuvasCIsMzqwhjlswQAjWNYhMM5fN6TFs89kJa1e4CzNpQh31zsxWAV@@Kyxwf3lCyzwJ4SEAl43xQyJl2BlUp5MyPhGr421/Osh3kszRpFuHs8RcRHvWWfHN7@hTbffbJGd4IxusSTyBkte7vqlTK79wBxDwhqOLizJBH2dg6ghmnj2sx4RwqQXvassMfQBgqQ/QIkNRyyGY5LgWrwDd6XfLZLqCDT0cqlt4YF4ZV02aMGf8u23/7jxawnvDUXqOKL9M7uOybUabnJF2JolUQsME2UFQcvwSPEHRyXGOIjnB8oYJIbxGwiTZrG/QlVXlA@5wrCAnXOBA0pcTZkHZx95@ZTnI2EF2@Cl/hlz@n4qKKU/duhNXPQu0NjJM6TDPpxBL5nGkj7soS/wqKzeeZ@74ZRgsQ6CnKJBAUGnXvhOLVxl44z5b5MOTfpVVpcxIMeMcv7c/diXZiIr3QOpgj9X/JhovRdS47z/HDJgByK58hcxse5cSL6pR6OrOvIMD4C0cHwPFJVWB3oFpPz5B0FouiOErFOIwQMzsPWVVx3rCPtIt4NZKw@rICBVB9VcA6P3/@FCi/vFnSBDMKXGAAmEggIFirzlF2KJzKD6BvGYhgPRt1k/KBfQivbSz8Tj61H@Hn6IP778SV5RIf6MF4fRb19KZCiPlomEvjbU@5nqkvF@w3qO1PeqfrO0MOv7wP08Os7S8@fVF9/xvgtVQSGGHqgjYMm@1OwqAHaD@TzFE8ZBqbHI9Tmu@nUgz6@yWcqNb2hYTa11e9bDt4lPr8EPM85haD4QDjk@ZTnUQI3GMgpPn2kFNLQ9fDWfUfiXdy2UF@MkBtficjHL9AnDT63LcZoCkDMRZrR972JKT9kEBVDSTDIE4l@/TArLlO5OgFq2zXtL66wQFZlv@BUUW6DMUrs1z7KuDeAI1B12r4IpfGSIKGibF6SAeodmG46CYbNTyKoLuTjZCqkOpubymtETC12V3qaEIkdeZdbSWOtWw6sNdVJOgO7BvQJ347153uHMY/BeWPQTG845o3SYIrttmm2bYNvxGaHYnYKjz2BCu92bWvQ6TK8KAp1QITlW8rbFmr3qF2CVo/vwRzgXTUlb1tcZFx9f/44xU77DIx8Oj@PPffVIdtAxb8xwrlkPhcQCQwTYofVwoKnOy2Mp7QXSNL7wJd8oo/POIyzpzYLFGAT@QGK8Apn4iD7I2KnORl7g1hC8TUQWXVdvOoeNWudVwGrP07Wx2WYcULUALw7vkhZWfBB5xeWs3GgtFS6YHH3gFXmlTY9t5B0DHW6kA0Np/rSjxSOzyJOz91AcTB3LM2m9jtoPz9XvnoNdv8XWBMy9bgyTnAaGLm4ORqUHTya18MLyPFmDc6pYIEDyn3LRttwFJ@L@Rbn46h3qbdge5GpjHCxpChOF@zZG9xoNDc1rbh1VWgqOjqAiKAEpFrxtTNcL8O3pmHqV2SO@om5AeyQKof3zvJiWE1cZfYSz1LCtpqa1nJQZVWRV6icETzeILqrt0rY0tUOWohgqXui1ysOzUeTtdjVm/xUxsYhFsXWPg50mxvbWJoktCXt@wFW2OhqzWuCxZcHjbEndDMBZDPdhNVmzseBauOUg2WzWNiRhIznI82R2IkzrUcJAVWeACbOq8wqIQFgVD/xKsgptvLm63CqxpN5tFkHX4URdsTrKcScEdI2OPeDsyZJBvLKn5CB4dkQJ3R1h/AEzO84aw8MlMVWP4lxKAknKxv0oWLZWKzwSwwnqhnwTABxwToZG8AotqHYPoYIDeNiJOaS5svgxRlozOoB4ASH9m2sAH19ogEpJ@g2sbxDh4LG8xcQTfPnEeQ3x4Np414LWxMmBKZJR@OUySxaGopnsZqWmQhi5mCziAEOwaJf236V/5faj6ECZKLsAQGDx99xhrGp4mQlFV1Yn9DTqZbIyKIqIAd6A8NVTc0aOMbod80I0gK9DFPozhA0Iu874Z1Ux9EM49ZZCl8GwHZTB7TdDfcmoKEOwjuzV8IY@USIGmy4niXGWWaIYzBO3HsHDi4TRU4wbk/E4eDo7QmYisErE3CmB7cJuHTGK863DYDopONippukdN4Gu/@nvWdbbiO57ln4itZQuxgQd4qSKILDpSRSu0wkUaEor10QF4vLgBwJxMCYgQgsha0491RSqXK8sWPHdioXO6nkNUnZcVXykPf1P/gL/AfOuXT39AxmSEq7XldSK5eXmO7Tp2@nu8/pPpd2N5zQJnrso3IF6pRO8D4IdTzGaCJGU4IbNvYFkfsjd8yVAbXN/IlQ5zPQa@TqEzbIyNemB5XKo4/w496M3UK654ME8CBuAxWqHB65RhnYfqHhAE53R9Budbx1XHlHgYcbv25hqEusgaqFv4jbYxu4qMI3ro1f4fDOF6tE3IlyNXQrAIvNuCVjPXv7qpTvC0rQT@g/Ecus7roULBOU1O3HlwTSqli8llMCrNcgRQvbc1BTYwMtLGBdAmjTO7zq4FsLa23Q3RnO4ikQiNsed4@hSzBfHhJMOKZx6nk9GjaQ4fDaW7syDwSgx5BEBWagh5OTDrqk6dN4aTNNevfAS3IAsSPUBao5Mr30aIfzikDPz1DVk@6PewW9trgqkktQ@AFAfY@EJ6hsE91fyoHB70izSY9O35afeBWygsOC302ZiG5KpD/6hayVQ@W5Xot8K40kxvo5GAvR5VnCJAwvvEJDxenUH7/glyO8dqOdP2x7dO@Nb4GssIyF1I0ePvIHUR6/ZKjLuSisCa1nPFiO2@HFl7yKmkLYFAds0MOGU9EA8xteI1Ja1trINaYt2MK6fANVlVmoGcVl@eWSN3ZNPOrNle8Q2TaoZppuybF2zKXAcy2vMtmubTzoS@4qRhsSUlIEQquW4/W7vJJUdZQJDUFx41nGocYXHQXWkOZOZTNljuI/t1MNn6QVd7hZU6uR6cNxmDqiOrSScNdQ1V1W5g2sTxYbfgpL6@gADm82brRj8HVqQ0ylfhdZWk1Zw@tKQv4W3OMmsqRXrsxeZ3RoLLSaeHQnbxE1y2VAcodWBlxh2khIeWpj7PPSTzFVkUqeHO4AjneBwRSk@QZ8mpfhQVjQz/VygQZhJQiJdoyTvsy7D9B32rprDwJfujKjg5ULBfRe@HovMWoFcvVy3XUmfWwKvvRDmchAZdE65WpfbzmkmssP/jxSBE56hxPEweu/YGgLKof6bLUCUGSyIl/4ZcGmuhNH9FKNui/vyLgHYrklq5V9UC6MsBP04G24syGp6t2xewR/9j1sUS/II7@kX74ruW2@THy8t/voYGe/tb/zlZ39JztUkhT5tUHxZFSlm7LgFJ17DyXefBBziJN7f@zBOY4nDsVZQgn8SdcPQ3EfxF0XxPEXbSjZnri5zDf3lQfZeU8Dd7zO5Q@YmSfje9I0Djw0EZqgqhL075QFcH4etoMCEz@cgeSQCrVeB@jJgONC5XDPhM2cc3D/xJXU8Sn6MkFIywY8Uvx@eIocoJQm4m/McNIMerCa3YrUsVXQeOUQ@UvQDhGQAYB81LqdVSgEuLlWYeBd4DmRjcS2cmxfkL3v1cRjrnabqhXb3C/kIdsDf3iUk94TjBYQ5waHVgkDjK@rISajIKgC9RbQUyCONPeIO1RF@aBar9Sqn59Lg@gR@zfkreANTPLf0M570U4/NX5Smtm@igFg8DjzhA1dLGxSqgVderSmuEFdoqIVWdGbmZNnW5NL9Nd/wxbkGQbksnWrX4zR@Odrz31pM@vP7GPhizfDSSXgmFWOIt9UFdP552ew83/FauT1zEUusqL40nQi3XRCBlR7HeOJ/HKetI@R89jd4wt7vGrS1z@B0u6W4YwSPJnatWKKtjqCTVxpPopHIzWRL6dEH9Ogj6mV/9rU4bP7mmILEHU3Xe34NXptGEfEOlp7LU14HajnAhV3U1t/Hmu/qtdU20eV9vEMec/oIg3XnGxuXEWadptXr0RMDZwtXVjHl8hfaphr8xblVN64jFPK6PLsUHdmXDKh/s6XgimldZC3UMbI4vBa8RBzklpNm0QJV2vEFOKlHFVQuOaL45dQW49GMLosJSdi5iW@bKu9jGODgajobEDbg0JyjmIoo8vYLJTxqVFzkVWZXGgLNiH6Bf7/i7WVJkE28PjSyOo3aGT1pdXIl1YjX1qNnGc1snS1OgnG1Y43rAJrNhDlU@D@c0uwoLb3xPvv3TkQB@/tiPtP7/22@NreU/H@nUeQsiceP737YPeegP/vPHqyI6iA/vcVd4wq9wKmftvtunQ7v1KrrQrCvBCgfFU8aZ@I9/yu@xKIZyNon2wd80dl6IabXGrnpTue@fwcNEJlllBaTdBdEb81qRsntLjuACWf4Dui8uWJbSRvngHfLJHtBYVD1wbc/LZHPAjpcdGzkjbaAHgfUgFNm59kSXcan9aJaelVhBw4/e@1RxCYwodPxJ1H2xjpc3v3YHfv0RNxf28fPh9/Dd3siO1ddBtz9ylmEeDDve3d@7v37lACN6BWEXi3Rgbr5zWhguA0Kt0X/QmGBxugVCi/Yl69l3K5oa@sIgKRnwwj9z09ICl8d2dnpw1y0W5fu7P/7leQq3G/LiwLg1waDtWlBcK1GhqNQG0yinaDnakja1mu84Z0MhPXMLuRozsg@l0SCnmB3ok9V1j38BoRH6QpbjYzbAo1VHQVcCMq5QjWERSBIZ8vbRDKTaiNbg9UbXix2lcfWHRLOmZFOXJJeWkNCCkGZ9wddjmMrkoAumetbqo2HDMAXgjJBAbAOxhMCNsv3F28JBE3JMQkRMEfEm5ywvOT0f1T5BrRwFUm3OVAIGuyTTxvNKUY4KjtDXkeY2ZNvDtQjBQqEhA8OskZDNSVK6nEAf8v39jwVRYgLdgF@7CylVARPbsBNcDeftzuh4GwnQLeBoMI4g491tQ6GrRB3KN74TEaLL1ENQKqds3Bf5vKUb1iOCkQpxJhOjMRb4cuty0Pfvey5aDk3YUaUW@POo0KUzL@04UNuLvQgDdBA4jK5n6BboVGITG2hMbvS1K2Ax8oEkQ@8XE8qpHfm3TdWAEp69jPvY8@KshBLkVFDBUfap3WsMNQD/gQcoo@qMjNBQgxpCl5jK9RPId2vAfR2/AJKkOMsYEfqsGVtZnCg6pRauLISpGfz6i10yZjuAtrJYpn3WC9fY20zyh6/g7YLI@eSTooJmtpLkB/zqjEgJ6dxujmpS9QsWgWUks4uEMu2js@FkG1@cGas7l991n54w9Lh9XqEW8L7R4/XrBSIj@zkEgOy0PrTpI2oFppEmkumHSwtNJn5N0SV7lCBozLsQfM91arofP4WnUxfUjxsuLplPjqlcOlymRvQiSEkWSi3a0kmqrKEpU5FAWJINo7obHoWVellAin3q@3MK49zkIDRmSI@wip15hh1Ui/xvB2jQ96sLPkJJ/G063xF1QscklR9M8256P6gX3XKW4WqgqKFpMeTltt0SWFuV6QvZrj9NJ5tYBu@3x0sH9fHt3aua3j4@G1sG2fi@212lYuZuPiY8nAdXm0H5@Dlg@3N0ILfS9lI@ZDchGbpnRNnKVrS4rmL6jxw4W5o7UHaPDsxYiqGqlR22Q4QA9xNl@KQ9OoQMFEEzFETw62d/b3hbWDt2zrUBb2vfawS/aluA0i7qvK0xHbIdNmV9FMkw4TpJknlTJn89J4tect5tTBy9gqJA9SkuOhNwsdtRckk6m0juCThVgINLzmDVGNXLx1Z2oPCpoS8byJmlAimjSjg7nUbi7x4cNO9mmTicatxLxx8MIbaWbGnUpnXXRVPZ6ZiBQjjMdB@whfvtPn733mj9dVPcxguV@fUIdRCb@L/vLFE6h4hC/FlfgMnjMtakpJZ4WodEmNHZnlxTnsz05QOhb7XPLCxrYumWPZNOaPrxmR7Ig/3cJ3/pnM7J7I@061xVPKhjmhhejQs@NHEDCZIAaLLZMqoPjhXB5hNBr6nHQ0Q26utWvUmqZqJUUzk7gb2UBvAQd/42Zye0hWBbvtuVWVP5@q@JSI1WTE3VqsQWUC5ps3bly/CHeyF6p4@bPi5jMkuX@GJ6OXbQNlMAtIVQgod/dRSeVHBHDO0DkgBfZstWASBYHVSTlTYn2nw8hsH7TldIy2eNCYvacHJbwvStZaENNE29Kx84lkYieQhT4YS1h3lFfNwujPz6/uLgV1u6C@q69fHy82BML78PmvOEzmvj/CrRIY8XGLvaKCSL4eoFZciCU4@KD29GvEwNxScSybHG9ui1@40Uaaa9wK/Reo168iZ8rYZhY@Q1VO2qOzV3jB9YquTDkPbQJkWa8ktp6zjgpH1tzq@aRE0NehLLe4lfE02OZftszgm@uoPkh5DGA8YDp6APNv5wXIPet4q6BCTeaLnAb8iU4qcxLQaoiyh05f5nS0S/BGg5lOr3J6z8XAczp1Q2I5beuIl/lNCZmMkJm3JDDd1Xr9WYuGXWe/w9nAxuikt2RjQLYc@Dr1KqeiTpVKasqykyjpkJNAktJJSxIKDyYvNGkpcN0XLZpkGW0OEOZLYugNDitSf@odW8qOBWnCEfJEQnl32MvRpFDMU41KHQlb6FpWklBzyzuskAKl3IBQJosmlhfSlhcVMIEh3Qh9yUTFxagB@F/ZCNlUk3ix5ubWc6TwsRt0J67YmaKMr2IjKqokxyBLYufRtti7L/b3Hu/EUWOLW8ijUCmlsEehmGXDqDtqyZZgwv1JeNziRPWZzD11OVeh4G8NNPTHBhB/JnNVBYTiEJelOHvVeyWacHiP9KTYvcKhnHTVY92HStefDMOzV9NXNL1T4PQqQALviHkFLwneWRgWuRIlh63Igd7iMCwk8pUt5VYhqoVSqJap9M3hS4vrxJovzCW2nN4/YepgZdImHQXkhG0SdwIfWZ51Gd8ShqN7HAXcpLdsR9h2smF4KFUqC8lFcUsHbnTNiLvxyi5ZSTGrkttRJUxhGk8lwDiiUW0F0fPFK@@Vqiw6VPDoX0tKO3q00XeznEbjiKFlF4OpHRrZ/Cph9LmXi/9aWHByBkU83qh83eAFgUHeo93cYRqPgRF9L4DpzUGB8QJagKNVEAPkZbIASOUXMbbSWxktvZQi6S2O1uNiczJqidClFEmvJWp0fCqitZ6Yja4P3BkHJMEfLRAEjfM1deaAbBYqzlqsIllQkiKJMy2u0@Y/hZQ61DbNEECPh@pn/ZBNb0TeLHYufHxEzBbIzhsDgnsQuVPBY81MryfTzSNJbBrFkxBGoxLAgDNxUl08F@xJJJZ0ipZavKzIaEtGA0deSx6NsOUcGqBEQhmg5Tgor5oIFkARhLg4PFkMUF6JcdBiOqhB/ARvYk201ViNGrSYDmqsjwWs5TSscdBiEnRhX6ONMj72mqFdts@fvEIGH2uiM6pyp253EvJJo5xWwBoKYXmYjJaE7nlHXviOiBgt@lWB9iDRrq5Jj9gqDQT8G7c060MFFKttNkFWGyHE3cLgpbyUivk6ymTfIsZcM48xeA5xje/jBmiTIMxpEOyBSTZEMRlSoFGnmGLFzKHhUtNQNMgYSVhi6Qw@58j9NpfOWNzhyO9WySrMLW5WI7aLQp9UspSPNjbUWFRCv@WJ1H8N2XjC4Y9EHEclSjrnXwzHJNSpeMVRGvhdvuwsIa6GEtaakI4COD3sJHDga8piX1RBQHN4cTvwQWURBzahKM7rlIlDCVWLOJYvjUMJbIs4ypdvB8lTaX1569I4WBBMw1G9NA6kwMUxtZbOAMGc/2ulkVpsPNAsSqa2S504aWic7dhXJ9kXJaoKtBckDDH4aeIrrR2SMTdpfWCIQZcaDxQ6FsfD9nglbcJRTDt3jS@Y61iysLBeWLilVL6BNVZeQ1wLwh4cBJX@QK/vlMWfENETlyQSId17oBBT6R6PQUTC2axI6UMxIIQT2t9qoWpWq0U3Q4/3997dv/Ow9ejOQxSilniPwusb1JYhdZ1aZQXj2fNtS4t0ihyBqhbYjRztw0YetU@i2aFThCLHYqmlMwNubjEDhTU5dF9UGbqn4j5kUdD6BZwIWdF3MzA9NrVBb@pW@aVViCDNE0z1Ssprm9ASgmE6kS0hGCM5ZwhbXP7ZkDVUng2fhQzYEU22yQwOzfY@Q8Mlo6AQ5ZfPwq@44w7qkpS101KeRVTBR9mNnFOhyoW8QY8wGBP4q2pV3FVOcaX9WnvQRZe3kz45vj3xBu2TTq9dGR2Pcv3Ake5p7Hw/QCeXOVSm2j3Y2X/SeoxxunbukeUE/mtQ3sHuw529pweY8wSyrsvknf39vf0WKajvP318gB5DE0mWCSixRGAyIQb0aO@9Ow8MGP62ZCPZICQAeRP@SFc@JeGNWlP674zMPEqsCtGiIDxkpoJFKa0kQu/E9ScqeBv6n1AHfAktT/BRBupSUY3JIY2N158yL/J1OjegqB3jySgkUNKAtxMjUYiXYJiT4AgLkC@iAPh20qav8I0y5qEhnz@yE2XRQAaL5aR9Vz@g1YHL5Mls2LUVOunIs3TmDgESX5vyk7BfXsvPC@hVckRKQ8nC@SqcHFVyjppPLylHUGql54wgRua1ayOnDN4BiixKaBIiyxQqwC@IDVEseoWznBkgSmbBrsrxo86EYUMfh5Hxa64Yc8RuTVnPF@pHAtG/pAWOphH@fGw@ShGByfcpMuZoouW5HjP6qzrLN8y2nh2b3qciu@4Kao/cgwbfCW129EI@@yK6k89dsgEtzEjOeDwP0Mu3MdlhqpBpPAgbMFDheCbYgjAI9XBBzw/xv1Pp2rWLCjQ2EFzBhLUszmV3lGgkFIQMQGKetWmtR25s2CxBKw4zxIYJUU@D@MCEWEmDeGlCXE@D@PQTBvH6drGoJm9TrNy4wdrMsflMKf5vuni5rGA3lCp0VBjwmcXVacxIdhiHhC46aA5qntmA3GzZzXNbFkf96b8DbhOXLFWmSrjh5zT7HMw//z1rnW/oLjFKf809NDYoZE7kkxebMON94T1J4qpJ0pY0ie0n52CzLDWL6WW/G1HEBxlE8@lPYzDpZPNtNe9Cj5964boSla1HVg1JBP@xiMB5HQQtLq/WF3kbZQNezF5Z11hUDyIEDHLdBFlJgqRV@ercKmsmvnpqlXUTpHaZKj/9maxTnl8pED/UELTXysFMBf2v2EIj1XwolAYaMCTa1DyOXn0zwY/ibTCLpYE/jrBTkcPz2/3zbyTbHZVMhf/9VOKkAiZ9qWlPHfh/uCyO65k4PmQU5XLmuOUZoljMhPj0R1E7eHiTy@y8RfLzP7y4dC279O9GpaNjflMd3Mw1KGTJLVCrB8UzqWhTY@P5gwHQKSmtMY5RveaMJYdnsTQYi3egrrOlxVk8e0Vlz1Kzr@vsBPI5M1iKS0L/esQYbXCEQWKNot9k5csMl8rcdEyurcAdMrldZtalgTmMjeZxpCmOwfRsJgSO5ZiQsYha5hYkszfPERfcSBV@gva4fTxsY4DWwB9WZAQQz6/unPjPPTyoxlV0c1F5HmRJQ5@FtSYEJMc5KL7eQYUKaKp0KsK63yy3I2C7252cTAb4huZIuQodI1Wr6DKOBMHh5CSQOPHEvTvxBtADBzm1iEUEMW8EraRTGFjpS1WfqDqt2sUqq1XWG6@QGzpKorZ1x94opMqcRVkAXT4RgwpVeBsGrGLh0UD9jBCxK1pH9ueBN3RtAx6juHolI4H8IhQdLtUgykiOiYGjhBogjyYnMQxncsZJN8bhnEqAFj92rbSCI@ci3YixixFCtHWEF4gV6YOOXMsgEmlBNI5jWSmtFniUCNFjIM@TOMRqaaWGFY0wi1wUkWdorVne7pPbIjJqJRyETUPTLABHGKGX47pZg95Bhm6XY/3ybz/5O6twVq2qNIqp4w3bIDNQRJIIK34e@I/Vt4Ee5RNpq5jA/fcRbkbdc7veSRsj1IQGaiCuDMwwgYj5DAgNnVb5A9hv/CPb8AWjKkTCqlbvbG@Lg/f2995Hayi@RCAqSBRHIlgXVpGHnUrG8qViMIJISliEeSgrRiDViEUo3SsE0z0m9zp929DAgtH65h/TaNFdvo@a7rwuEwgx22KnPnhPiLq1Jlo9EYqCcR6@@UeM2R@x9mw6Yn9kScKEnyMXiF9dRdoL/WKI9Pp@8f0/o@qkRQnwfHivcmJWncX0U25TXsgSzZbrh5m9ilVDg5CJ@MIh@taPCVnAQbrVRpi7Yu6KGkl6t3/4V4Jw4OMDzJ5RUsTwFC9E9G1GpF8PaOQy8ZUvxPcdxtfz6BXARNSZxbv4EM7JyhiNhmwjuXrB8P3i@7LFAO@F@GZyTh3LsebmUifjX82ZpbJyOrLm18CfOcM/MJFKM9csjHxQpeL55GfRMjW7ya6Tmb6vGKsz0bTUDn/yn2nURzrmsHrQAzijNacqda1ktPkv/lLjn@auTC8gmF/@7fd@FPVxmtmzaWZ/vhetpuliL6ZZbb@S2JK@ikeGVZxmTsVP49XEVu7UMT6zEPwka9yn8cGeZi15IH296KcXLPssJN9WSPSCn1645LNwfUfhSl3syW5lLPdp5jJX2DMWegL/ckYzYTH@i7kYp@fNfOaazyaLvyHkyPCh8ejCtFSrksOpEWu7Ier0Fz3z4t/NZGvM3Q@v2iLGxQGOCtCh1BSjPYSabpgr/ywZU37OfE2UWpfOFlSPjFrqshYQTdqDIKUqx/nc6lrBoQNxL6WWzTerJDevVocuG91PRj2UOuj97oQkjzE9/2HwgPSd8Rs0l8Btg7jC1jbknqBJTT6kF5xggXwQHfkcUqIGeoDugbhBfzd0d8t1TiF540oSy8BnlugKXaejKJQpiEhJolg/TBUqWE5NXQj/pHcglq46LF3hYMk@kh/ZKOfCzftbP9I7kh4lP449gbJ4Mc5/lNNAKkb0Vk4eOyRPl43aiX1pQSqeqo6AzKP7n83dIlFdNi9pgGVh/u6f6IPODVCXtQf9QZNX8viPwTFxYDJPQGP/5J@EwC4sR1tGZs1/qiY@4B0qq3I8yS5RT0Y1P/4DC0k7fZA4u3GxkCUxZspYYveRePpkZ1/sPT14/PQAL2RMx4haBs8W9Fjs5n2ZBNj4JcGCLNsAMX@FxVkjj8nLK3nFlQJ1/8@/h91ntEXHqlnGMJ1b7gexcnVV7pwxoqm49AjJ8Vkoz5cW0DquW/bWcdbkCIEAvTsMcb0GLvyQYHwxwQ6f5dnG5M8m06bULStmPJeY@s@zW8ZlTPZlAh51OAFOXeD8ObUvKeOLoQy6sprh652T9prH@KEXyuUngX7RFBS72Uy/8D09Pa30MTzVZOxV3ADdEwXoGK46OgJmYejTpSa6zQbC87og26Lzwkn3RfSr3G0PX7YDVJB5Z4oq0c7tt2f8N5d1Rzw6OuFQHG96TywE3faWZqVuCZCVOt0Xpf5pryEz2DBYK5xwInI/Y/VxEqhf3qivIfwQ79l1VmfwousPiNu1OgM4yKyoau6hgpypT/k98tgwRl0iz6T3U0FMs82KFAIfDSgHfgJXpayLvWlzdhgrPtXFY9osAUfEPBcpKwRjPutxUNiAKedPo0pVtc2pdBavTcjw9QGVQhQkopkpmJhFOOZMWSl@E1@oMA0hZ7E0tPzpOlRajTd/wTw6ijCAJkYw4K5dbX7wrPnscBi4p8uHxepRCR0dIXRHmjXSmJLPHv6Noz94ORj5QSxp6AYhK7jUVFL3WFID0worvsixSmjcQLO0wo0XDRpqBzqUiVv0ndD2pJkqaeMc0/O21bSiMeaGNWVjcKQ9pWQg0/DhyTC1NxEdGogwXXdJReJL04Wy3h@jPy0FW4YxRwcwwxmaEWKghvhSkTFMxTzeKnwt4wQYdvaBm@iKyoepaCayjG7O5fybzb/62s3vw7pIbz0RLG@KCaWxqQsbriuXC3vE3HSMeYUWVJfbA3T5Z@0MyT2NUhwsNJaryjSF68EuyKCzxuR3peMJfkkdSi0UrGuGsq@YObwseV2oIdWaJtErPOUrQpDleQPhCCIpxVxZbGoWA0mXNw56Fksrdmo0ckqNnHIRhp5mNPJQFsNAnqbbhkN02taG8wjw1Vmjl8RCEbRfYnwqdkW0XNV1RnsOUYGyMIQJRTrrHqbW3jQabWxaCQRIiAsIem6/PRmE67nkhlcv6y@9R/FQqj2KvyQZ8F4BBEZbcIOVymxNZPLFAq/SPXJ7Cb@aOateqpXq9L8a/98qqUT1//piYi0OWY8n1kqJ//1aEg9xZNPFonptFTfk3K@WxGgWHvvDldyS0Ge2oDMb/RHyC@rzgN@Hg6E3GrkhhTkSR@4QH7cx8Kvn440FOv/CuDrw@4VL/kXWFXLBT7Gt50ELEbUkospoJqxrWxaM@8nIH4fio4HXUb8xRvnNVfUVzAJ0IxW4LvFAATBB8pkb9X0PxrPdcG@I9xJV9Jgc@vy7M/A71RMQ5d0xuXIMYM0DhOdXxpNhldxNucMePouTGUL7BTTtGKqDrvVaANbCbtkFpLzARfeU1rNpv2@R8xZ30HviIuOGt0dCR1LZ7RHf0Q6OLdzWlsQjYMLW2d2K8mGivXTRiLsiLx/jygOO50waA3kj0hdqvGMsS9LMsFApWr7Xk@s/q0IP0FDKKhBbZhfoRPTDCF6pcsoCrBgSK4F9xCB9zBjjWRH1CEOEumhZIhtRFEImUDuiT1lplEAVyfPZKwF7iL1SVrSuDdPKPGN9Hd174l2ZUy/oncJDO6n62jrG5qCe4IDiNMmn4foa5pCDykBgxDn2TWP2o@jIlgAgTwgFQgQee4weGTrPSYkUL@vg8ED6q6g8vJ7ooEu0AcV4wfuroXtEUVLEacfjUDA9LyAALFk9@sgbySEqxUi1MzkCVpvWAkVW8YJg4t64tbZKDaK4Rgq053djoCtVwIyuZavUuOPwZKB7cTs8FgP3pTtg/2/cbIr9wouS6MyW2ydeN98sEOnAUMZ6CqNg3y5x2vbO/Qd3Dna2S6Jcv4HgbKCqYW1jcDm7SPlkwCHJCIvw8q10bq4ykdtBKb9VzRdk07fMYS@aDVYIYM8aoxw3svMOFZM3c4wYRKYe7lUlHW9Rx3ZDXW1cbtiUyRijFlhqcNXKX1qykKSxriUkwdjmCGUK0aEBX7DxLABl7hUwAnJ3a6EQhqGEiHKtjavlsl5T6/SrDBtrubzJdubWPZDDX4j8/mQY223ztHbaIg@bHHrL463tap72hYrVEMdO/q0g30DuXHNOL@1J4UyF@Bv2sRU2D9yBf3em5s@eKK0VGJBCs35YKMiE/P/8N4h988gsYGCHhTPkrz9ylEvYCm/qO@xB087zbTAU@6gSutPwHm2uoRM2dIGO35tVKCRp7x6cvT37I7OOkV04I@3mruNcL5xBleMR2qGMYDN0DwBjoYFp/VhaJHI8ezZEt7jLKH999eGD92DK99G/VBA2PzhcvlYt5fNwxJMGkoORPsT23sPHeJMwLlToRuH@2D@R4zJu60oq@LCPlsPU@pKFXaviKoSd88gNZe@Du7OD9tGj9glIzG0YgvgFTtvU@sEw96jLb46RY8Un1yqcHTkEdTx2@w3mhOaB89I@KjRC@HNsVnEDqnBWVgh7CIUcdCCQGHVvCKf1ewcPHzj5jbZArE7KqsgXO5o4gFCIYGxMIoE2RjoYThepKmS7TSIY@FfMW5vxvmxU25v5xnye2Z4HfrvHHr/yEQH37ElJUtzYWZzSxjiigtnIdTCBj7Z3dw6sEpRF2RcTKcbRjDYtdkbsqDqY3HCnoCNw9gRhHGf17bcpDYtMAsdZqdUKqB4yB2zkAwLQ8sIaN@bjttOz9UC2R16Frs7dKddFzMlKZaXaHganwI5W6zdrt6/X3vHH@G7Qc4Pu2wFsIU4bQ8p64extNOQndbIjf9B/u@8N8MHq6ury2p5393e@evvJzW272/kt4CGt54GPD/jjkdmAcftUav/BHjvuMnVRI4aAs9uujtov/Opqr9Zdq63Vb/XcWzfctdr1te4N9/rtzu3bt7v91bVO7/at9q0b3U4V3UZTkcoJKQ9aTP5Ybf9y1WYxZmsrtdv9fr1@81bvxu3@7ZXa9eurnbUbvdrqan@t3r5@/WZvZa1zu3M@1xa1JwcbrNp38exI7sBvZTN3uYW9XZYu/C8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=
#*  
#cs
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvw/WWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $cand e&&195e a 6  \=>axfnuen _e=B[;#]>8t t47576097  @Numun Cr Uu8 gurtyX
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc;import Data.Functor.Const;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,0,211]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a)+l 1e1+k+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 34);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on the work of Ørjan Johansen – [original answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153927), [version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167389#comment404689_167389) adjusted for polyglot:

```hs
main|let a=0;f b=b^a=print(f pi,f(0::Real a=>a))
```

Difference in length between `"(1.0,1)"` and `"(1.0,1.0)"` is `2`, so it needs to be doubled to get a free spot:

```hs
[209,210,128,206,207,0,211]
          ^       x     !
```

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,0,211]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a)+l 1e1+k+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 34);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )
```

#### DOBELA

DOBELA interpreter installed on TIO (dobelx64) has a bug: dot hitting `v` in `import Control.Applicative` does not break output, while it should.
I don't want to rely on this behavior, and `import Control.{-_-}Applicative` does not work in Haskell, so I switched to modified version of ApplicativeDo [provided](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167537#comment404978_167537) by Ørjan:

```hs
import Data.Functor.Const
instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
main=print$do a<-Const[1];pure a
```

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>import Text.Heredoc;import Data.Functor.Const;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
```

Because `v` is not needed I use different extension of Grass code that does not affect output: `Wwww`. 4 more `w`s can be added at the end without breaking Grass.

Also added `_` to Grass code on line 23 to fix DOBELA (destroys dot from line 24).

#### Perl6/Sidef

Switched to `` #`{..} `` for Perl6/Sidef.  Looks like curly braces create less problems.
`` {{{{`}`\} `` at the end of line 20 fixes Pip (`` {`}` ``),
opens another `{` for Sidef (`{\}`) and balances `}}` on line 21.

Removed redundant angle brackets from various places, major change is V (FMota).

Comment: I was so surprised to see you put the declarations for this at top level. Apparently the `Local` in the name of the extension is a bit misleading. Thanks for saving me 4 bytes in the original!

Comment: `B` can be merged with `C` and `x` with `a`. Also shortened some other syntax, hopefully they weren't longer for some reason. [pastebin with TIO link](https://pastebin.com/5e5EGAC0) (Also, I *guess* there's some reason the sum in `main` isn't just `0!61+last(172:[t$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"])`?)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks. I think the reason is to get rid of parens. Btw, may be you know how to modify [Zgarb's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153886) to not `import Control.Applicative`? It is 42 bytes shorter than oisdk's answer.

Comment: `Const` works almost as well, and can be imported from [`Data.Functor.Const`](https://tio.run/##HYqxCsIwEED3fkUGBx1acNYExOKmsyBSjjTaw@QuJFfFnzeGLo8H702QX877UjBETqJ6EOhOM1nh1B2ZsjRYAWSdOjMxjgq0qQbjeskKNp/JJacGY/SggwtRvk0AJB0TkqxGVrBvl/e2ve/iXF8o5WcfHp65tNcLH2L0aEHw7Xr@Aw "Haskell – Try It Online") instead.

Answer (score 9):

## 216. [Silberjoder](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Silberjoder), 10345 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNdiD4LM7@g30JkfqKpHhNUqR4EVlF3UqqUkkqXUpVJbFYSTJJppTMzMpMSmSp9KHds/BOj/3g6fEaHnvH3fbsYL3AAGMs9sGD8WKB8evAmN/w@WlhLND/oPecE5HJ5EUq1ddt7CwwKTEzMuLEiYgTJ06cE7dsynbv178O4cUODW3U1QyHOYrtsLalXitWkq2P2DNZtXOZbCCAUDWrO@grumOXAiEmMabqLbUN78wxrhRd/axY4J9hzLSMriX3mdOTHabYLdlUbGYMHHPgMKMzP1qWsa2@cakmMGZf1bsA5iiWaSkOha8wdqprcr/ZlqdCclMJmhaE22xT0b70vzisZfT7st62ATLP2CvDshWEbym2bWD0VcaGW0prCmkBQGVLNfZq@8@ngoqMPYcsyqamDJnctB1LbjmqoSNN0ux4//T4cCqGJLE3J9vb074Z9jJh6Gx70LqaDsqyU8uWNXka/wqrDRxj15n2z7FaV9FllkkWk5npwDxbt@SZKKvMUuR2R9WUJFQIS7CeopmKxdCHdQyL7UKWtEK6kG7UxjGTLYxbGAdOoy0yLZt1psqTSQPhDaun6JDD9HSg5AVOBWS8gLZKCcjWiEXsnmEBH1lsYCttdmNYbWAuXRtF4xCfDT@zpmwr@RVEkPUQXOnGjQ5M5BhQtc2RozDd0BMUGQFXmLTXmGasTA59awe70/55ltmb9lsFRmtddWbrMlNgR4Y5mvYtslfq3jx2zqZ5Q9gw2lAbU2ESO5TBi5KZJHw2M9kKWlC70JjZpQ0ZayvM1lXTVBweCLyiWBQMsZmm6le8gR9aRnvQwsbn9BRIGxss8oMdaEGsKjOFmEiig4WIgzgY5ODY6Cv@/NpMV6CCbFNpqR21xRlLGTqKbkOW7SRToRA3qqaxtqJBhDH2VpzZBlbv2Kupyb1kKxlAxsRUWP9KYyprmSbjQVAKyNJ2usAUpB77DOFaz2ZDs89stQ/BTsvodBSFfVbMHkQPtI0Ag6tlThXLe1tSAEZXXNIoJggEJI2BlAY6uRS6sWQgrWULGjhqHwirOmGbKbKtokCFKLait4mqpidqDSZPsDy7VqHBQ9EHFuG2FYuaHOGF5mkpgFL2qjlyY6mOQ62G1dihIlvsxFKU6KTYnUgSEjMwBQcLkqRKXVsLbx1sh6FyeYykbEJlWtmT1y8CMktW2FKjDL9KMFgObO1vstulC3RzKQsMYFoROcoq3zM7dXGhwG8oNVNd6y4AWANAFY2lDNNJyQkTMphwIIMpGZ3oSlxnkqbmS5itTdWFj@U4VBtqA4QPexOnkrUGloU9yZio8hUUWjP0LtATCmsNdKSHzvJpqIKWAR1BnCnXQDWQvFRHIBeQwic9FSrNxirxNSzeHxJBoUcENhYUddO1DW1AcBDTdpCXgSoQFTHudtgb1pFVDaNAOKLiubYUe6A5GGegt7Hmob9T2knmZoMarAV8fA3JyYCUPID1@752SZkCYKgIg4qKQT/8wZ@2u13AU2u1QLYJdn3D2kaLem6ZMgvdIUOGBYGqUbYALo6p8@iQwLWsqW0SELI@EklQJijVG2OgtZkBCVo3KrTSnnwNLRsaV8tROJPzzj7O@vIVlyYq51woeF9uQsVSApQ2FTvBnm1ALbWUQIh4JtEfOJ0CS5hbLGynPkSeliJPFy8UyFw0GV1eSqW6ZWC45DJ5wVv4Ic55U5uQlLYj24baDpgjp2foGZZosWCrYpiKHglP4AjHw1YzHE2ilItEy2qlleyoejsSXgNerELC4Wi5VWmdq6V6eSq6P0lAc4NosLkqkVY0GACRQ43iOtUHaZ6EzuFNQrh8YYbdQJJjcNLnjYSZ9rvmHiFSdpAvDWQQkENJW1MUM5JOSlEUEwg3t9wYMK@kUzhEgUtqPRYOhWP@ohMGKOlEQbGxnqgGii3N7GGnBUTRbRN6Agt5twU9NUpGW3VA44yzJvE19SIgWUgm3ihhS8Eu3eMjapK8yWH8BApKgWHchCZbstL2NWQQAtCWHXtGGmvGDSRIecJuBkSHjonKXagaiMwLUuMF4SmRz2SRuKIB2JoKKySaKjQCbG4g0wXP@8oG4NkMhwFsvJH4ZE9fHgGWFu9Wxw2GqR1oS30QD6ANtRSUOSB8FN6hYCIDan826NiobacTmVxuso3NNDHHStUS70FIf0492JKw8P7GhIKGdZQbpsl6dyB3Fa6JMbnVUkxHCCooie2AKJrub8gzITrPpN0LLD2bTps6EVe1GKeBQp7XnugKZZQuQtFPgDqjMFmYKqA5WiCWtNF06gBwPZV48COCTGTgY/CeLLgaADCZMlRaAwekGjDwTU9t9YBnMXc6l4u8E5pOHrz8qYNkT3S8pDEzUvVJJpBMeV6YjXtRJLBGZ/FA54qoqhMeVPl@j4cxy3Z/DmLDyyJ0BD7fZEpOAu99BWff0I05SIGQHloEmQzh9QCa2DEqlNBxuWoXNVZPy/SqCOoMDYE28l/PcUy7BP2E6vQGzSRwSurEGu06BzoyS8qxRqpjcHdTM5oglm1onyk3hVRr0FSHUwUiP68OL@3ANShgHZtVoOf@NACui4Q7NghM8t9AYF9QkAQ3oeD3IAASUBIIFenYJIq3Qagcj/RWJJikppSERheMsyA23CCYO0GM5dFlw@ijFGJnpBigpgdmn6qjrSBkPol8eW5X58l@0uvC4eSloeqR2/Di4mK4FK6CZF9cfAquNXQ9RVcMXE/JlSAXwiXRRTHi5MLQc4qBfvXw3bmLeRitY7UNsVf6rJoR@bxUytbj8rkknhl8RkHUgWQD6AQ@AE84WqmgMxoNVm@goMlmZ7L0Gyidj1uWagoivJCvZf4uqJAlMqh9E81ISyljJ/swTfoVC3pBUFpbvYgVvjhPX9Qvbi/asYu7cBxjR8typQmFgvQi/WTXMgbQXUbPV0oJqR6Nnmehk2xWwunwciRSSGiQkByNfleIxmRO7UhYAakdubgIA1EFfc5bPYvwDeOZaNQjFeQDO2bQCSPh5G0B0m9G69FYGOJGw3EwMSrhMFCmhUSwqdDImRMEOjh6yQmzEYsFiA0N6wp/M2If/JJgYPHo28C/G8eTZm//CqQra9kaqiIJi2sj8Jpa5p5tengaV4ntksaqQ3cLJYDetu1ZRmiN6wPSn0m5NfwJkTmIEOSHfQ/KVXUCBhF31CEYCNDuR64ihP036kIbYHAampI8I9UkyKDhoNmrJOdqQ4e8W0m27DEPgN4DTlOTW9CwJ9FdBNkFIAQ@T6Xmh0TLM4inVSWyar5WRuhYWrKO9GurpLUPVLuH5AXNCk0JqwNURZUddAOFqLbLWtDnd4HSylB1uA4PfHSMUXZkOxJFrbHGtS5U9lBjwEy5YwDUnRstsHcU0BwwlBuPbEu/Vi1DRyIntwA1MHwZ62AK@TzyAhvVaruZzfvpOw85UGzGW/LR1o91mrgtu8VSuqEZXYMtAwCyZjLJGXtXx6ES0PkcMC@ZrX4mAtW6hj6a4kEFu3sbdUQpn/W0bxkhUwSfvARZw@YXegxwT5mPd99vQQ8h5dJpyL/7lqbLK6QPy3QZ0bPFxgBiyFZDvsGafK@YvdHEgBLyB7cigZ8MhTdMbtfL0KFCrkQL/0xR/Y2c@0A7d4Parmte2bdIQ8KhDL@VMVF6UAahnYri8GYDJQxNeaOvS4oJpDMVPq5fFFwXqQm55RlOiU7fcOTUm2TPZngLoL6QUFnQToUXw6lEAu9BCmKZKku1lesUSimBGaTySW@gBJRWz2DBC9Bd/EBBEKE9UMITUAjFIjXPiyYGpwOOMQB9sa1oal91dmkgTdNRKRp3@G4ojgeOERyqihMQlsxYcONg11iK610OvzXErs4OKPRk@webW43D2slOJZga2FZKU5vQNtpKow8qrabYQTZ9hdiRAshE/M9X2pFhOBXOCFca@@oVwjhu9L3Nxt7u@lHt6B3PBKGx1f5AkzErpaUpAIx@TMFue/WNMHYso@/p@raoiKUskl6ZmE1Aw1eErmDoQMwl@Pzz6N/H@YFkK9BttVjC4K@epwBcRUCcM6DesRuLISTNIXieArJAKHEeIWk1Xc8ienozCBNj62N088LvjyQw30rpO0Ru6wPb9JXsVpLI/9rpdFAf8Lwz5H2VwEakjb2z5M1nICbH/gVZZoLmAnv4Vggfn7mYi28maC6why/H8eGMx3x0UyHzQD1keUKGMyRzcU0FzAH0MK0SJv@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@uCeZyoKkyEYZcX0PZknFmQ9Y8x3zUqNOwRKInW33U5UV1A7viDdrbA5zHc24p2qCtuM/5iZQYEXlyOI/pap@15kAT7NTII0@MrDfNkNtEBm5jqQpFsrCyeTUoQ25t@JRZEEb3JTRngJCNZ@Sc3sAZ8DtOwn2tGlUTf/cRYQI2nZObkpIybLmpKg9UuyVfDdpGwrzqUqExa/k5sOPyN3E8K9HR5CvubKBzPgF4ES2121Us93kf2E0PzAayd1I39HiAM1zVipGyLD@E09L4/T4QdxmM57ifTqpGt0dUtMdQxCItaCRIWpxpT/jIpE4RVpObI7T7et/OWZgg6awgZyqtWCydxU7Wm1YZz@mb5v3xsWem@MXi/Nh8jp@TZJ7NkuJz@wk@5kVlFrP9X2nk0HWpfVlLZNo@571S3B1PHbvmgNIgQKKlyTYwkyOqQ7mG6qPbQwyOvVEL2WrseoC9x9lxZ9fum6gRrVS05JahqTY2Z@0@qTk9tj1OE1dZ0G0cFd9mCdsmNdjuJTzXfElgtBycJbmH0R4h2fgEBU4B@TgnadxHtJZxg797lYueca3w@/zO7fPcXD1CRiU0Ygm1NVeAtltf41ScaafbfDpezc2X09Lm@ov5gElT4LG8bKuaYYNNjveHSAHatW3z@3wu9lNNlfUEDVv73fOjiUyZLCmG6e6pS1nrGlq@0E3JcLu3wgdWByW/eD5W4nkSS5K@LrFcPcjQJfG8V9Rfpayrr3ECjW1bOAfmcz7Qz84TW2Lu5P4Cgv2AE9vzC7edLlDMZIoPkNxXAVardyOP3OeP6E3uo67bm5gj0qtBzcMIxQI4HIvr2j8mtZWHU2s/TiTNoF39WiF8lXulKdB50X2mSlkmLX1jDCmdfryA6mgDZaDMlU8HzUsFlzY@YG08PlNpUYwlMZSYAuLhQKIH9VlYjY/KNfbb@PaggJE1FRr5V7WbufLOBF3cREP7EByH6JiN2NUH5kTlTlhr@tHDlOuZbss22hOZxJBvlUiFr@tQE@q6rdDvPtV@q2@AbWz0QW3QH1H/AimNevD7BGLyGSsaE4Mjc5P3JspBlwXVA2pUvbITOC7@OKGTuc@gJ@BiMaWruuKM8H4fpecJ0aZhaN9SMyBL2yotYdYSuGj1azU0o@aINRNsPHRh4zBIs3PfoAXvZ4RxCdRDu9l5wFL2D0U9YA3ODKs/0Fv5Btm/Zl9CT02jQrbVct33MSQNfkjJQnL1QXbkWqjRVDSZP4b5lYfwFZPZB/F5WodQb2lSBidy@NTNeFYtNCV6zBEQS22DbdJT@gq9PqDUy@3Lge0@7gUaGvibE5xM0UTEPfFMFdq6jveJaSKfNuQYOlhTjmx1FTRHNJwZFb73yVd3fmMucXf7clfhOxweEh3jUQlcTMeNuLFz/vhEia9vaUE0Pv3/MCtAw7lSRrb7nIvw1agF9Tnof31UbaqNt3D086uNOpmaO63zFXVP7xk9vaf0LGoc3tt9zQM40uF7Ux4qBOS/J9tXuHqQ5NHYmuvZfupqhqY9hrooD7l0NIz5A7NbuPK/DVG/Ce9IbkKAeHx1xA66bCIS9d33tZ2eMoCeyTYcw1QS9HYfqIaDPfw@f6x59yBsszNVsdp86QOo45C02tQUdqNCFi5t/7zz/IGkpmbIuED1AeUdKOM@HzM01TKsr457dGXDMU16NExtYNONRnQTtE9jXnG3KaePYQbV4atOOMsqXaPZ6qlfy1JTkR1dvUq5Yzj89UG7VAhjKrnKEpvondRUoJU1SiITVPzhx/jYva//803hzC39xsCyRl8XDJMz/t5QK58hQMd96YvJ2TnB1OXjsip3@dAD0xRiLvdebiIFGpXlhJIGrUS6dwRoYgWZkF40qXiP0jNVbsqMbx7tW4YuxWIAGsRTfQsawH/e4MV9gnBHyDewCiM7g64d/Trj9tqgU@FtLsJaFzdr8ZkkWzNufAPN0PRlXTzm9srerONDUyC5B@dAkikx15lQBveObmmqafM7S3Qyc7HMTt7PQo3mW7qietpKh09ToOtrml3fsHAZPagQiZal2C0c8Ubpy6UiFzm60QUpnNDYGNiFnVuE2fUC83STyR4u8XZf6cq4rG5PxRV2mj3b6QHm6aUDj0H8eiDb6uuB4ShzcU4vIXgMyldyV23tTNSCi9ClrliDxR8TjQC9ZivipqfatJrZdcxvOJzNaDZ@NnB6UN3bVffwQIhPLxKLSllil7mLTz0HDutjuDw3rUmtU0zE3yvoVIcGTMVzbjnnL7d4aBThZtA3B7Z4zE@9j3sT/CPH/Svyt29UkIKJTyB0WU/WnPmjy77BU9CnRE84dt6nZb9XNaPL3hfSDNQvEHCodN/DWOvQLx/KDrQAfQ6zUvqPnLfEsYkEV2rsT8AISpYlVF11Hh6HcRwZ7CD3iQXiqhbuvUnt4T357FsxJE7mU2XvQYkPXfqopYFl8zWow3dfgVA2vt61fGXaBbpKQx84Cdyv@FAXkX@wiyixYSHv4wEWeb316jTqskK31@JrGb@iidkKWHQDWxuNXfdO9s/hMBX3ad8vZGdjuKbBptKRB5pzhDN6j4lXM00NRzZApm8a80yYwxF0Md9kB0EvMehvKi2cCXxUHvaNV6CeQb9lglTtHyk4dT8lSO6PjFH3jJasAc3aj0rumNDPK@uJbCrrUOfaN5aXY9yUHXkeVgVH/zpfs99LOBvUVKxLvmf9fki@cumINuV627fsuFh1DH6qJfaO2kl3g3aIVmjTZi53cw8L4RazAaqJjmElGcFFInIsFo0GeCScauvqAOZC0RZZ3D7Hd9/aDFqjQ7Bqh52fs6XbYSldku5YhQVLQVavc6x40WauraFJ@1uPePTzJbleWQonEuGl8IVeYumwB65o0OHMBZcnYDsqPXh@xyRguszX4aPbLXGZbw@0e7T1FoyrNhhppzqNnaLBxze58R2UJ7iW52//si12JHcVKGxfBaUPCIIb8o2@0jNunvJ0RerQlGTc0Yw4QD/Q@P66xEaNQccF1hzfiGzcsNPtk4LY3ih2/8PLIdf2vVzwysXxRNyc4PDK47nxFpqLhL1YbqFATA76OtjPbadnJ4GxaN/BwBov8wUXgumOhYMI7TjbZW0Fl1DQdhIaN9MM44r2hWFO/vYv@aZO2lQiFvu7ydNmbl@KuHdEop2UrZYxgFy7SD4rliFAIkhk0BYGOCLNsAMh/yhutaDdpsCRCXevJSXDN1xu1I5ZYouF8WAD3MJVVjuRpdrR8zfn6Xrle9ZPKf/5J6norSBc8LtEMW8H48wFKd8hY/mDcxA8Dg2z4NIwyBP0dtyoQvzd8PoAEsmcyXDTjctjhmGKVkP75Wl7uMeN4tyWCLqpnt1Nl33aak8Mq9zQpktaj66j8MM97LoNDQxeo4Sat7rKUmTAB04Txw7LQYK4cVUGF9@cT3tQcAMhRlkasi@sh0yWaOG@CHjjhNRwz2q/su4uqsv6lz6mNpXmgJb7XGeSmWyFirPUqKxVyWUpbQP3jp9/uBhm0omL4epWPWW7RL24GH6XzrwFqhsWxHqSwpa3tb95u5Sspr98seURCwbvwmW@VBPExNLt4e7h1vFJ7eT0GGrhzhU/24bVl8eyBrmIdjr0DI125QNdLFWxv0H@eG8AHomwJZmt4Xkz0WjAv9SeQAWtg4ngEnf6RNNE7K9EnxffVnzhswBCpnVU5nLULnQDWIfAbEg1LPzAxLMFmIgr9kcTl6ko47EBeYTBBbFzZCmRKsgqQKwEEOuRpGL3F/Yp93sMxb6K5WGyPZ0LghTz0jv3wnkR55Lg7rdSbhM6yt@83BzLw@UmmAfKDaCerxtnu7a7d3q0NRkNeIyeJHUrxZzYY8KFM7Y0PubqbginjX4iIg46V4IsSBH4q@jM6DChpuLcKFAsIRxbfR6ZOJTyHwyMGRMoU8ETmeplTotIhHKAOkgZizW1BaajDn1ZdPtoH7pbXkRPCGwHPdRuxpNBgTlEp@Mk8XKLgVgFudymd0hCXMjrsO1Xf@Jui8OiYR8N9izFuqer8nodm8G/r1dyXZk6GzLRnUl1lmAZ@GmK3oUCu7DRMu@j2BInRHCJ5z3o5RdPZoE8tS9lGvuh1Zhilw/00pps4jEQAnrfcJQS@zQwaLOiK0w8/eIGRxZkfggRVW1LxtLQJkjdwSMd3H6L8O1uH1dQO@OqGcl3P88NdOyoAMh3JBCYLRae3tQhWc8PF@EkN8Q5Fm5XSZMBtti37mkJNrtWbZoswErooI6jgaTE0oiC43lctE2V1TQbdJI2dN/89CpSTpK0ZYDvG0joLBgCnkx6KmOcBQMIa1dmzzWArvSmBd3qRx55ieAIs@3DGV5bTCSAcl1Vd8@PKuGcBg32lphjDXDlTTU8E8XNQolciZ7T13yAc054uVBSP/zBn/JTXS4ccP9MuIfpdXj7PfHWAffvuyGSBG//wnvLwNvP@duHFFbZ7FEWInlh6t67vwL48llwpkwoE9xDtKgsXm1jTb/ZPWQ2TbxgXfbloa@aUMIgz6k60EvtA1NcUx0jOE9hXIVjPJHzN8AiwFfAH6jeoEZD6SlWPYIHGpRSKcw4jg4laVG@MuSzLnS@wacBnusDSlgqn8uvSCnIZOLaRUibjLu4LJwjjEZLIBMD16pZ@dhs4W4fFrTBLFUq@TLnjdSS/CEb/OhldAlgA9xQOGcQBzcIeTEgrCqiRZbkmBTFqNiRhaUwyrS2wVkNtMEIOQAkit66u5cS1E1DkAr4WFeGDmlMI9cAauL5bTharPDTnVxECUDEcePpM9PNcbzQGzfG@Bpo0l8NwTMEO0awUnAes55/YBfOhV4XpxAxYLxfzmFdHdz/fM7RRJyzcNv17Jk4kekTbbA07NmxbuCGgG3ILYtkUplsSspHfRwaFKggv9jUvwBKaNwgLFqKemmYdm1ja/fFweHxzNkuBBmeBguzcHUtdpFIxs/rniPs5XuSqOvbqeNX69suKf25Gq@ZQYjxwpnpbM5LbTqn96R@xlfYz6ZNATMJSenHIqZZ6sQ2rSubxT4OTfkAN/gC35lUI9Hbu/P6WvVCD80k/2XeeVeh5DIyF7gubDrtKjydTczirrtv4ATP0bST7gayTHB8mpu37Y2/j73vP53FO5VzfESLu0MhQFucx9ugk/fsXYCyJ1M8KTqfhGfMzS/IGjerEmZ1nGArMLPuyZ8bJsoye4Co2MPnEemAjyG5xz/aHNIm4cxHmeicJI9mHtyJixGb/vjQFHFaSA9yp6nNwI3Y2O7ugPQ2tSdtU1OdSDSgC4jpvZCzkPaDZ494YHLlfMi8TX026ozDJI2aR@hor5t6gB/dwtwTVmJ0SMvhAOh2aJhsPIq2qbiuI9Cp2OaAj6Iq7MWgD3Adehwp2FsooGUlIDLQM@xm5RyPJRGUSPbbucgwmuwpw7bahR4nEo2DaPpOksbHu8h4PgnoVc15JcBhKbMnQxmwarJreDrKMLpWpNdxAfl4IruZ763XA4AMozajJT5yET7V3ZO4sOJLLBz3KNOMxsNJxi0pccgWrd2ggagk2@jhSlca@uh0VFLZ/Icm8M68o1r9JJYKuhnOQs9xnbufa77ppB0fZeRzOanqbWUYwUMNSnWkE/iHb86uw9HgDIvTcT/icJf29Lk/riyUHSGUxmfmTMm7YtGTc5OioVjEgxFweygYJZDisWPtgRNUhEinL5ssMqCDk2yWZPQauYjocduxoixRxe76huksFqMxDXhQANgsCNohl0onVETwnMFIqgKVhL623sbHZ9Vk51IyWQc3JRJlSzieuQHaFI4ERgNgo0KUEqEF/QL@SpgjfipsUpwOu0TJBujsEoCaG0xyCidIQL4ALajUrPrEd@bDWMBwqhaLJVEbk9K@yIAv1uYIREA7R4q7NgLQV@zvA6qhjAaoDUtpqyAvn71UdF0BAgHP9PEQXHkATGZF4@75zPHx@YmUQohncUdsGISMTp6ruBW@1XDeYSlVpqGx8h2oNR8vUK/pCM1mlPrvU8lU@TaypFVGKdA1o9XIUq8ixbLLsdiSvhxZ0lHbevIER9TulkCZayTBQB0CUGJJi5aBn0H5qyzp5SV5LbLUrmSWKQa8gol8CxG@t1PJ2yX5LrX0BJSlOPhYXOhElmw68iidTEp3kD9sIUupOPDMLZ7dQ6cuY/JLaiyGeUguNTAD36cujmPUbV4cp2jwrixsgVS3L5rblCrm1cTMadGcgMK75HVYOeywxOLPhgs8PlUxOy/sHvWPJ/wSl8gzWtmj2H7jKzgZ8njBIuQ0ylwhZCL8zCkg4DACRMTXuByNgjD59a9DUp6x4NN8NmLEnubS5Vg4J4GZDvZ16Bno4anloBW8vdhMXDOlk8l/SpzLneSn@uHV4eHb6EWEFVk4tHEQlFaCH/Bg7Mddqyxzz8V@/BUKLacCodSy9GQ1lfr48SNYHHCdV5NVEB/8ip4nwvXzyCpj1dXV5Xi@sBx/Fm74shWNZDLRY6aqKXahmna7DT@jR0ekR0L8evqU0gLzH/4Z9xPpC4f7giDCN/SNcNdyLsQuVmV5ObaSeaaXk5l05m//evEufnvYWPvb3@mnlEV8HODjZ3ev0H0s5b5bXPxufX1lJQ6E5O7D94fvarXaymY8d3iee7qSSC@u/af/c3Exk1nLpBbrti3Vw@dXb4OZ9Eow@bd/ET48fN2wbSBEEa8sk8CJ9wL8JJbLsSv2Ga6rDsN/cn9u@9wyupudz3jOFNgrFRI24XAuGz7@EJ5fbYtMqj5d/S9/ePAp5ISqmdSZBU8n9CmUL4S4ExzwlnXfrkPV0BqC5e9Co1SlUgHn6n/59xC/@gLwYMhoDW7VnIsrPwpVExWK8iVUzYNDymQg3f/7Jz8JhKrD0OeQJEmhEf010A1X4Yn0hKEjFVwtBA3jGR7ijtfQd41LkZKkzIVbn77qxqr1vHuAG@qVGT4/r949rmKCG8jxWLgq3Lbw@rv/4@/@@O/@kP7@mH7/Ec8Gzy8@@7jJmAI9MF6l0rOZetibej9KJuBKeq0jhK8JUbJQoRJv8Fx5LBzyOabo4N2ZIIn3/o1wgZB7wC3KofpEZVyEpMLKwbPhoy82zrRL29CYpF7ibNrPrQzvhbmygH0LXCD0faVy5ODfqyb@Hdr4xx7M8gNHLLGncC3CH/3D5b3ifZF8hDeBzF6Lv4H0DYTOQ@f1@o6Of5969GfhX/MT/u19xr9PDv6dtPDv6BP@nXzGv9nSBEJra2uhWOwIVEbBtI@5TuGXTDbEm8e8oUDot3qxADSHeixxd3ee/DCMlcviH/SosveGF3dBjup3icTah2osdk45O6@KLK4lVg7yB@xZvcpzTfdk48MaYI@tna@tVYwN@iUbVbwS9Q/V87VJHISmXn32LIZN9hmgqNbPzwOhW6yVCt6W8day8Z4JBlP0@gUlPHTZxUAItd0iV3qL3IO@coFvgdDH24@R2NPY07SWvk5LV9LVK@Ng/H9wMIQAdZi@NKx0L92T2iAyWVo5TY/So2G6bxxIbXAq8Jfug1NNd4bpblpP65I0Gk6guv@/f2A4rw4MwGZATGeYdhBxugPP7sHBK8DXgbQv4U9Np9NDyOQwfQ3/aQ0FOB2gR88PDRa9hevj3ceLu4vAOQt@VEBRSErhZDqczIfDaj2XNz8F4@HGxXm4Xg6l7IuLFFehWGalTEco3t01Glv7m41GCplqKfYslngGV6UaWxOPp6Fq@elFKYF16dZqKLX29KKaTaA7H4NqyqBf7BuvMUZ4VhcvAmATnp3h7@zm@oa7yIGuizO6Gjz47CzFvW7OxHUDV@r6HgQTDgba6D/Sf/vgv67/V6cscl6PMha5vVuL0BXFv2j09u72Ttyr0UhEvETW4A894B2j3N5V0UlAt@A6j0Tr0bs77gf3SHSNI6xiGmtVijwGhCYb4qlehMuMgfUUERNvFxfDdDpaboKPNwQvf6E5nGiZVrcsNXHeDSwGaTlKILmVcnlFuFcL5XJBuKV8vlxe9qDS8CKcAKTYcquMfF4OmVHMA@f@SBoHXuiY2nCkrXTwewVPTROsP6mY/vLF82o02qrVaKB/9suXC2hIYVzcUinmwCdd@PIF2mE4CpbhviGmVYtg50mpzBh9T7Zlx7EiYPvHL8K4itC@CEcxPJNOIzDGZ7m1tfxKtZpfAXe@EI2Wg0t8ZUykGytK0bulVJAXA2y2cEgESYXVKPnehTGchdbY0ypwuI0Xu70LEbXZSi4aaY6UqOchFYvch63kI4VYUfxVFqMsVV1m4u/8PBtbWV5dflavj3tsFBLlW7ki3VVu5RKOI9yVW@KMWFyzKz95ki0CWQrp8kWg0disndQa@LENnKMGKczQk8RNAOcfTSt8ToM@uWL9HAtSvwiHS@VnvF4LORYKlwVcIgyCixWKVN4QWJZqBxfrDwEr4g2EStJyJruYyg2/y2@lwSJaxuv8/LyQKcSWQawtF4v1ep181yjGeX/YqdM5YZXEuZTP1ROox1wOO8shk0mr2dBywKSVRqtp1sbJWgsH0BbBE6qUNXFe3VY0zT2S98awtPaN2lYWA6HDvdrG1kk8swYoM9u1jXjm@HQ9JOFrbvxOwVl8P9qqbR6cQoTDva3a8dbz3Tdbp4fgjwd4wtU/lJWB0lBuBoMbfG8odG2otnx5KZtmw4Rr2Pnhl7/7wy//hx/@/Oc//Pnv/vDnf/yrX/zx78LvL@H3c/78@b8r5vD@q1/8i3/7w5/9OXj@R/j9B/j99a9@8a9@wn/0/jfw@798fn8jfj44/gsArt/71S/@8C9@9Yvf/xP4/Wvx@5PZ3x/89fzfH//0/h/G@8N/@zDMz/89/P43jsuF/fmfcT98zsD/GYf7/T/54Y/@d/7/n8QfOv/8hz/6G7yJl9/9@Q8//cMffvo7P/z0Zz/89J8C2/zDX/0S///wr/7hP/wS///Xf/MPf/U//cPv/S/k@FPu@H/@9b/j97//nd/9@5/@y7//nV/cc//dB@@/eIT/L/4RfB6fz8fgeUy5vtXnFz8qP78JNcapAA8AI/3zH/7VPwNe@iP@9j/CG/x7QT/zXryQGBmcidjY82eMfUmBKpd@9sUDBZT/M/qCN/syiY18067vr37xL/8CvSdg/5kfQ1qahV1CYC@1n2Fj8DLmh/0ZNqcffvmTH/7in/7wyz/94Ze/hxI2sVKM1@IJ6SvjVgCYewQcAuYfAweA0hpO4S@yxUAGHItrOM4SkGIfPwJZF8EFVsFyIJeFt1C9TobFxXmqepG6qPKrDu/JVBV9kqmLFIYnU2BUNNh3YJDh79mzZfZdIsGfY7@AVCXUkMcYdDQSWG/LfNgkhsYr/IaBlSK84UBKDPrHGA@KQdB6jFUqlVhgWIEwAoVXjDNk1QKaxWgIVgAvRuJx4o0CaNxsuE5YIGYldsQay5UhjxhDjyphYJgh9DoKSplgrFDZhAQrw02GuBB5LPARnh8r1UJlWEV031MWAEdsHZIEqArmblj9Ht4rhBPgA8PN7yErhUosVi2AT4WKSqnFG5SmlKPCUdljjMqN/mCuw@PpM8a@C0qFILdUoWaYgMZ7bAz9lAZsnkL4RWxZFIf@XSf9ljE@VPuQ6MP9ePhT9Kb4AgDwJhK4egx@UI0A8AyChxxVjJKFR4xjAMrFxPiD50HaSSwQo/qN0QukD3l43LVW9b0gOizO0tISuNaqwWzwAOwcZl2VbEe2cHKFFLgSC@aLQfTGxTjK0iFZQsuby3CX4H9rkRbUcnIsB5bCqKyEmZtGIpY1VowQ5d4tGpVlmXIeI7hAaOzPlW@aIQOteYVFAxE6RT9K9rRimvB8ZXfXjSEoyPFgMC7l@Rh4VJjb74xSqfK9tLIagCe9D/AAf3GUPFQDftQtiY0VCVq9TaxRwwUnKFT5QLUqZvmYFKgeb51AhJMDJmXSSQZa9e3KamYlt5LLZPP53GpGWskXV/K5QhaEXj6dy2Sk4spKsVBcvaMsPQPBES8tN3Nr1X8yc/13/2TeNd8Xr0D1LRsmWeIuUB0mEqkM5bgi5VbLowrkg7wCVVIVuf0wuk3g4s7ABS0mu8V1S5CtwG0C2XQBLhZYCLAF8IIL0OL8BhOT7rsHZTH7iJ9G4TOQQSkHjBANXAAjcGwBc/IKYLU9AVnzROLOXH7sTKPzBHfq7UMKUAk628N1no7BTgy@nnBdaQXWxB6zaiBAkzXnQNJ6AL88cF4PrKW80PmYNnr8e4EblgHq94@HWZf1Kx60qfLdRV7QjozHf9l91endA3Fq9nEfjmL9o2HY6jchgzgoywHW4WZphjEPYJWdHt5Tylfezl@c9aStvwB@tPt858T3PNmqbewE8mz9YH9z6pETQDm2t7V94r2u8lA3as5D8W5rb2/6VTzQhFpkudV4HKQj3PAZp4ueyaUPLoiUfGBEFrqm1BpbQhs5B@2d5UH6XlSq8rCjD4C9wQJsKKxRWT@XyqF6tQBSZmU1t5pPF1ehue4P@gMkBTsdFFh34Ix2D1i6zFDusZW3gVe49K0o8S0cqh3YAburj98SwHMonICltMEGu9Fpd0oTvwg2MNm9nvBAL3RaarcHGbkxXIBAU5YZ/L71gviK/3Ie9nB4GuQ3E6LNAcfJPrXD0oEkjc5lioVcoZjNFOKFYmElB@ZpLi5l4tJqYbWYjktpqSDlC7miFC@sFLMrIBghNFdcDYRAgKidVArkvhQM0lPVW3je7xoenGwke9VAiI9uQGeLn7oMyZ4H1EwwW7hIQ7xgAJf1MrWyGMSPyabxU62AUGYtFtre3khvbweD6/iCo5Eb6WCwjS@5Qjq9uh4MKhSyAbI7EwwaPA4EAZjDX9Lp9Y1gcMAR4JblYLCHL1t51FuDQRVfNmrb25jOJb5kMD6AXfEQ/qK5L6sApuNLNkuKbzD4yUMHcDWe0ArldAtfME0M2eYhGxAWDD5385NOA4YjDscx7LhlrdWCwV3@UqthyAsqeI5n9SW@1OgKBi14AR4MBrvg6FqKogeDTXAiJwaDLXC1RjL44dnKuLtVd@RgcMQJhCQKBocELbeugqBRCX9MZmdnR@45baXLr5HFny3IGoSow8HWdvP582a327RGta3nRxjy4sWOfDkaWM1uU0RrNuAyIA6EXPVH0xfkcbfRkLW5IS8hRJ8KaYwaCuatIX@CPImri4n0Gy8g5AWEzJsF4tjg6gNoE6/1PjzX5SaFuBeF0HPYbAbLyKPOyFRwFAibDC2PKvt9@nLLMsroAhWcLYYj4fjoXKrHP5cphPUZi0Rv0@U7BOlE6DsxKCFB37kdnQ8r6Too3lIZB6gii/2nQRB7wdKi/DQyRHc@WALVeyUYLeE3doxOmIUT0tNBIZhfDZaW4Rl8GsyCcxhJh9OMwS16vlp/GlxFJMGnTxNByAu8AogMEYOrRURYXAU1oHwH9HCgW2oOHKXRiERuFPkqGuVl4t/lYmdnZ9FbviRMpTI65U5kGB9WeG6YGi1/hsxPY2rjht5ByzEsjq8LFPj8NF2iQkLyBUqepVLRNZRIKEPg@ZFG2JOslOCfpJEK@WgSV5A3jE6DPg7BPrrD8GdnMy5@Mb8HqohnuBWEtoG6a4ZIO7ZLgRPUI@mblwwPCmjiZ6Jo5y0YKPzEEvqokwJaZTEQqArFCvf8JrcHOpYuiR@ucsoi5EQZOskdBVf2tFy/Db7hMrk1xG87qobuBhyPQDvoJ3cPkqe6LXeU8m3iLHFHu39x6ybucVbbTK5UwSW3I5QQk6M3lOdGtVppVPpK33RGYIeQKlz14kInyNYZh8RNIO46eOg0oSjpso4nelAfujQMDQPVNu5iXq@s3w5KJYC9KysVxbIMKxgKljtP9cqAMnioWLhlY/dgqcMU3BvR6n282EK4DaDa7V2iajG93K2cY7pf8LaWCAbricT5lzoovJV0eRSSK/agSWdGsHQTNPJ8eQh@0upKWYOi8n0vS7T6TS73WLPS/DAsWxVzYCllAq@cZ9LFeEaCvgn6LPCA3yq8r8BPgl@mvrgY0SKSIsUdY0sHOqRLJSQH0JFe4SlHY5llLdI2mLyWILJCCyljGtAue8xU4RaBaEeKrHH4aOzT03yCZYvRsp/GkWg5shit2MqncqcS@RAtfwKSWkuRdnI9@nSl3I6ss0YUPKC7hV@G5Ve4cv9Fw7HmxUYlzdX8JXvQP08v5qX4baKRuNNk21mSVjOl88HSeUKCEqW/dNeC76vBOhDzLgAWgX8oHPrqMvi5bYj37uP@eexnlkH90hQgvVTMlAVIwBQtORJkEfzoGl/vFQmHVzPhcDRcBqhF8CaBEL2l9hsGqRJ@ArIE9AMQJsUMhFuKMwC1FKTcTA64KZOXAqG7QFu1TbZSDIRuA3e3d2tVV@t7yUYjOZZwX58w1o2BUZuiqbtkI8QWyZVIVp@xWqXWPaqVBWhtg0zPVIBd8F2EidTit04QxtaqH/jzAmeHIZkAJw5Np6fWYtXURSAYxOYgZnYihVyUm7zfh@jYU7Zx20GRAA289AppJZeO6WsE5/Xo9/uqdlvIJqpkDQHX3N2FYlA2XChSTRGlWge0PiMQ0g3hxMF@B@QJSMtcLoiWscLM4@KH1Q@FD69OD04PttmzdKlQKnAyXHBjNS6FpTBYws9ATVOPtgIh84uRk77XX5RDJTOcXQlnJ5Tti4rYQB9BJoic41QY/OrnYPPWo@CqVKSn0mpJtcVMVaRkD0zFij6V8plSJi1FQ/Yd7u7NrIboKeVXQ/UQR7myGgU3zbFkpFA1JbylVYyV4G/AvbmQXfwSyqQLgVDh1ccvjLmfiVYz5EqlRGaX7tbu4L96dw62/h2Z/Hf0j7cU3O44AP1jBPeFHuNrAm4MMw6vf59Y4/9rdNs44DkP5qEiQh9BItj2h8aHRigQKobBWAmzTE7kcSjMaFS2l3X6U@xl/Psw9li2bXvZe4PXZSgzy1XBzllOpVIX0dcZUMyLxbyUCQV@PXullsHoX16osTA/WYz3aniuqLeDLDzx4TYcp1leSGweH2y83DrBbk3R8cO7bONgP4lB@G3Y8RbAlqbIljYSH4cdIRT2hicbh8wAw2rzkOKc0eZP8qXhGJHK0m67JL6gFL9mUjKL84@5VHolJeWYVCilV0uZPJNBDtl42INwLWFURsXaMMwRN6ciG1GKvFBDGAzbU8HAtZUSe364RzHoHIjlhc2tVwfsYH/vXdL15f4nO7vH7Phg@@SsdrQF5Xi1dcyCtWO2exxkZ7snOwenJ6y2/45B8FFt/2R36xgRpAIow1C94wTzbBu2Zo/sFOp@Nhk4E9620bpSnEl/2TLlFB6UO@mt42dzFPzYxKT/QFfBevLbTse1Ba5IMUQvt9tWAHedqi22gIbTwjL007jptZe2V1lu8PZz2sotstbKfniVtdL7enZtlWlp8ce0lX72iC0uLl7oQa8D8BfDM938XrhfAfzGedp9v7UQya@wZTDYMivRccj@weFC2n1bODs6WZC8sKPNhYz3sru9kPVetuBtxXvbPttcyHlv67WXC/lxtP2NhVXvbXNrY6HgvQGTLhTHOPc3F6R0wCXWNahSC/RpwMj27t4WWwagaHkiFAfJ0DHlDYSIgPrDjwAhW3V5@aZnxEnzb46moNvK16Bd8AmoBVTAzpGu9ThbNky4gWoHwBAt4KnistVtxQVWPFQKepbAbWABC7SABQL4Bdx8jnBsscIyUQbBCx2@FCLCDxmMs@CpTVtMv7PZGurUVWCGOJ1SRVuNIYYivhEaWLgTKCMdGkjs0PppAgX7hgWtYDSK@xP3T/f2eGIm6Y2RIEEyrkTOwWmYgA2KCHcsOvjyyuHVQnWBtFoQWgV@xzRwN1GbgenaRFJAORcWWoBgkrrXshZnqFXFcZ4d8eIL3/cAwBAM7jS4@MbMSKSFZe0qTosyFEVibh1s8xLiTH2FTdZylGGiRCkK5jsqvnxh7tuFM/lqTb7qYY5bIOfZ4vh4TisIG0W/BXdHLEHQ7n@KuYAcE4tBbCgOhfnKtQBEhx8/LMDNZRUSSofZkyeUjzV4K4YpCYwXoxRZAkEQgSAYkQ@ReVlbpOxGF1LLuIaGVtTQQajYj/Bza5sj76ATkKzTGZ2qVa8VetW5oIMpWZ4SyCKo08a6Bnc204B3FI/AyXHWhGYSZ26glMdAtLniTImzDnhPydSGqgPnKtZYJrqsAI2Ran9/k9cQP9WH/LkHlRjkXokqDITFE2y@xOgLC00LDOqyCwXykKCAb5FpIkgIDvdwvKNNirbM2wuyJcZ@TMzd7ZLLRzw2sIPgNCIrHsTAeUUUlzyrY6AZ/AIZtt8KoOcsyZHFYgLC4zIBtjUJl0hwuDuXL79SiK3pUix@cylQLN9biq1HFuM3KwV0a2MWgVKAiI8A3hhA022yNjPzUEBfSCioND8OBXSgY16CNj6B4BHxocsdx098e3zopEvTTRnaLdQglwo8yuRra/K1PfmKzRd8ZAY2QWaFfWFNdEl5cOGGfFYAR5vLysmInclXGpKpMMWN0/EkME8BeA5FJQdDBpwVxihBkjZ@Y0Pu45eeKqy23djd3zqZDEV8SbshMt5zDF2jNKKTYCJDGG5H8CXq5SjSQSJwfTNyyNOIEz0bxydHW7VXcchflK2NW8C0DgA30RImSnDnpgC@utKC/rgdZ5HjGluOsieYszgTgwX48ugkNMNWANW9KbYHZoaSSnMQ732yJYWwRQbmJBWMsEiUfbm4gC41vcqkvvkl28/qq9k2G2VXUdnleDwdREh5V8Ds86bJlQ2EbPMDFUtzE7tMp9mKlWWO0gONe5i2ZvFTue6wb6Nu0d02bBpklNllhru0UbaIQ1agX5xUbR7WIqlvRD5AX2zG4IfdOQ3jxUg/R/akUFfB4nlpK9@al69ptJN5SfC8rFGis3n4tRj6BHMpMLU1nM6qMUzHlHH3tAg8oAHTQ/SyAgE@zuI7sixi4Nd1nGiJjppBmdJo4EmqjUbEVrQOMKsxsFrQ5aO6bAswvDA0yQOpIaFjMlCQB/WnyYC2irud8ZxK6HWmEOJhIuCNByRGKMVAwMuZ7Sgm5cqXDRwnw89O@xMEA3viHaoVdyH6chwtCa14W8b24CI7nzhliuMY2L34HG8Qz7O@HpvOCfPYZk4YHiY4L4q7O35O2OWgPy8HIBjuCRH7W@eE6MbBvAj8kKZxQP3cR8BzP4Hr9Uh0ftVDu5qscd8pW0T/E2ugiCOjdg98LAjKpeBAX12HNhVg2paK3yyYRuTtsIeYkWHUt9nfY6vomJNku6Wq0@hdTAIR7ValY/nZsNTqAdbvpEwhGvch9GFs83Nb78PJfEghh3OQhNgx8b47Amp7qJEFp/GO4yfxrAq9DebdOIJhPgCPoWNYrHwXeAGPGfNCPGae0@TG6EqzjEP@OOiO1S9NHMh2H7RbCCnqJ@hvmnziW5NP@NLHNvmjkq6w88l81GO@9xJ4jMvoNvAflZCb68nUot9UYj/XKMrVPeyLB@f4kuEHZkwm66EREsjjKbcohB49HikkEJcf0TfIF6o@sZ1/Xuxx/7NcYQnJi8Ml3rg10OC6L/MBPOqj0cAzchsNOhyx0cCRpUYjyFOgjhc7PH@nKxobD0uCltowKDQSTMjBeDCRqB1v7O4mVD0Y58fAV4K2Y1hKA884C8ZxFrgSJIHVQJieopmVoFibJ9uMYgfvT6PmSwMK@PVECIinsqtTIuPDb7@eXMtfJOMRRTKmEhsfyPmI1I4oNTx74KGULH6ynZvQBh2@hqfZWYqKgoYfcC@@2Y6nlEwcjoFD@iILPF2bRvpsPJKEZ4keDfQTdY1ne@ypZFXTaF/QPawnOHO2jmjtONSDCMacyrkveEifwWJ0cFtbEXoWDQ8lg@NDO0XGkqKkPn53FTR@1sm4Q5s8wEfkN@6OTdo4jDmV1bFgMUws/HkQz/eBCjg0TLh7Z/yA2zvlB9x4zg96uaIO3HjID8boCIc47wdcdOIPPIG9g@MDRvvyUO0PcODGf4qE0OTG2cIuH0tCvT4FTko/TlGESGp4UnNE4I3GgqUgFN2m04WmTxhC@HmHDEXrgVkhS0diYzZ9qsM8pHOPLYrGfwuV5FPEUDTbIjcQNx5kQa6EUFypVAfj08c7rohB9XnKz@CjnogIShL34o/7K98hRZUJ8wIpAsYDz8w4Ah9l8n9ukpT7aMlTQcY15ofiitucfOPi2nsz7sfgKmrRwAOW1P9v7CR/lfxXair9f28UzZg@/8imzAMmzDdbK79Fs@C/KfT/TaH/EQr9b02bv0cln0Y52@Kn1PWvquHfrn6RzBtBt2F1r3HoLfNj9LDfkiKw@k16gJvrc@khXeDr/bOLJuPv1n9kLx34deqknT/bNmq12klfso6e17q1Xu0Iz4NaT@/Fzi5X1jdv1p@vt2ubm90X3Y195XWhtrJnvnxbePe88/mTAtr7zsGL9581s9ULvD0yb86Uw5usUrBrg8Gn3Z2Rs7N@2t84zr1bvUlvabnOuvJpU7M3X528fXnyPHccu/n04vDF5366bx920nKxn915lX@zMTrTA7lr9bS9vace9I/bW6eZ/t6m@m47tpHeOy6@ltJ7Wzfvsxs3sVw6tWu@PHh@dHrZ3HqvHe3uvWtvfDLk/KerG3M31S52Ni6P3gQOsq@lnU8HB92tTPH5Tupms2O205kdzcpdvj06XD99t9N7KW/1t3OnxbeXo8N87/Xra2c/1l05yw9e2Ssxvfb6deal/vz6euso0JSNEyurnBmvJfPm5tAo9leVl/s73f5rS9JTB7k3seP@yc3m1rr2aXWYPX139vpm5fjd4NXrF@8P0urxcXNLzpvNdub48mQl0Opnd2PXp1unBfl5@@x1/3p3J/duM/Wqp@zX2ofa1fPuznvj@HBvt5a1B7q0t3GtvXveu3x1tbmxqxmHV5peW0nltJP2u4ODwOkLtbmp7Ly1X9Que@9SufWrlXextvn85PJz7@rF@vHpQSEzPByljQ37qLnTGW4e5TOFVEv7dPS5Y7ySTl/H8teXLzLqu9pnJ5D9PMoV97R3Sl9/EWt13w8/aanYqSRtvN/9/O7d8c611azpp5/ebB9dWq/a@oF9kD568fJVU7sqOJfme/34WGqlnytXr2JpOTA83bGhjpQTObd60t97bQ43jU9Hu@/t/OfY9dlVVtm8OnpT@3SUbt7o5lvd2lP7G@n2gVx7Yzhbg@HzVvH69GpH2/t0YL8LvNqScrlto2Ovd96sFN@mnsc6V8/frkvHw/S@ftRZyVv7b16fqepW7@3p56NWbvuNWeg7evf159P@Vmxrb9j7rBTSTe343ZUeOM0dHx1mbvSXat/Z3jl6lXcO0ntvDts7I6n2WpFu9NWNUW5zaOWzZ5tvrXdXO7qZeqd@GhymletY@53prLxWm53WG7XVfxk4ftE73T98c7Oby1vP@7q6flhI7@/tbOx32ysvR7uvBlt7zcv28923ylvzJH@V2Vo/y2@@Pc46J1cvnWLrup89LMROtL7TPY0FXgx6g9XDM@vTm@H7lVq/qWSPtHfGaFXqb7wwM8M3ta2Dz92rQ9PYl7Yzo9TpnnGlpT@f3HzesfO1UawwPHX6hnMiDXPS60D25rPpvDBfvD4@WH9x8P6FvKKqZ/Ll8Zt2OntaSKk9K7ubzz@XtrY7/U/9oiJ93nyVlbP9Xszeu0q1N9qnb86utMv@y/5lK1Ao2q313fcD2dhqZqT0u/XOVk7ZW987kZTT7svjlc399OHb9uHpp@FJe@Pt4PTNgZreunxR3OuuvD16U3y5@v7EPpHPjLcvrf3AsJA1bClfzN1kj4uFg551nD27LDrvX17m17WzpvRiN9NXtlXrbWFUuDI/9266N8dKutl9vvlJPupsgSQ9PUzLucHV/vA4kH1z0r9eNddj765aL9/qklY4U1dTJ58ui1e93subzdbKWe3zJzn3/FIpHm@nmtp27nnsaOP14WV38@xzYaWdXt97I78dbvWcd4HXO@rmZfHs6mA4kl5vH4/6tbSu5a6Pz3LXJ8b68dnOcaH3qml1mjuXPZAN/dHp5c3gekdZ7Q1vCi97l2/k9N7bwoZurxymAy@U3X776OTl21qsk1GKzvXBu33zrHA2zL0qGGdF46Cgvqx1ng9fH3S20qumenYyPN3qpdY31H4BZMqhdmptHLzeeX/2wkwHMnp@/fOGkVv9FLsevsufpQ5je4N3rZNM/8yydt6q1vbb68O3L49ru7Hd5uj54ZV88G4rd7y/sWG/iG2reWW0k72xaxtZrWME7P76cH9omcXs@6u9LvQERrvYfn6SPdPtWq1zs1s43qrVntvN3RfycPi8swp9BF5bZ2@MSuDX/Ky/AD/mjz9kfo5IoG93m8YQ5CXf7Beg3VsB2r0V4Pu1aIk0X37869Ry4MS/b4E@lswHeAZNUNZY20DlIcl2vQN58XsccdY3ILqKrpZh0hPRiv0ZbTT4NLjTeBVuJ6RPPSpDUzNU/NQRfnYBbVJr/FW2ZOBAZ/0R2puO0ue7KVT8WpE4P5e@1MA/CkXndwYWWi3mfhAzSafDep/H/AgKhKl3E3QccJclEq2OJndtcGhtcn0MHHvH1WMKmirj4AcmIe01ZCmdE0tT6SN2mLkT/MjS/nOmGfw7EK7FIYMyMaJzVHCQis5SUfCjebZ6rWgj@rCH0k4G@IrPR62C9Pvh8u5JPzrDdGptKKgbijW1ANTkEd2Z1tTyMzzi5tlySkyxojLUkK2m6uAnmRt8X0SDp@iueTMn1x7SLl8xQcsVI9Rs6PTfuNimNMS3qVhIMVpm3qL9JRwBqoaoorqrDZeXTUJJ664Yf/FhXjbvx632u78t1BO426oygdcAWg2AVjQhPTNn/51Nixw9oHKAT9Zvvd09aYivv/AlhhObn@5Zcemjctl9M8u8BL78i5zPLsvEFQaQfRx25IdnQ1GvDc7LQVr3iMsjobbRwh6vtkwC19BKA8Rm0mqU85U6X0GYpqV7LsG9OE84Jzzx5erJmKALYkGFxwOPjMcXaHKQ2fIi4o6lKARAqzndrSFTi/1@y7x3T800NVm/QleZL5UFe8Fq@SqLvmvhKwcOZXllEesnyUbAckNUbxnsOKNBy6sWAhALYt1qPtWxOdN6e4zDa9hLGsfHMA3P6tI0oxUZBy@7S2542aJuShx@KqkDHEns4MpawxrxhHB4JlIuAwiu0yGZoOjualVfqStjaiA6WtTjywXwbdn1wiMFlHE@4@zh3PKkFokdaAXQ/KzyxUAIde5lq86Tul8WAr2j/sJMRB0Tx11CBM7UMnMME4jQERwH3RjxCF@dOkMVvtLL4yLG6XSersM/e@p/KfGFu9igFBz2RBESxWaMFvpU5rxMI2jVazqY1Jj1qKJwBTdWoUq8yFSw8NGfqbHYRD35kJ@rSDeJxYjakTmhIIa8EgnSC9oTDK2Jg9rgS3FZh6/g4rQOTJFoDRL68sVrMPDqceOhu90SWML7ADwyOOdM3pYFQcvuu9sIPTeFjIniSdW72bX0tNMUDHDjxlSHihYBgdnAr9qYDLzEkiXT5A6C8JYvgTdWNuVdyKvFxQjEOie4VKHOnrCItLYWWU1EyOu7QjTqNUYRPeOL7osMQrpaZZHMciTrRl7ByIAyO4lgZT6CDEewshyRXAQZgUDKAQauYhCS71iBc@0k4oIPsYe3PgmD38aZk/pyJibV19YKuMbT5zkVOTM/68vZWAYic9QLsckQjpYH@PzrkyUC5NmMrx/xoViJZQEFTzo2GTBOdSrAS9Sf5kp9buf0W1Ne3H0abudD0fETnYp1XsDyIqfyRekmA7fpWMITP5Nm0sfSxn6cpZeRzUFHoCYJqfUU3DQV5x/LE50W0K881Sv6NkcQBIoBIoKLR42zy4f6uua3d3YI3KEBPl7mOJPirABmCEgUkBgFiAwihGigdhutvunBQVdciPIV37wDo0T2ccYZ9w9APaHa76ZEYoyTD2e4AZ/4WBn1IZy@EYjQ2Ntdx8ebrSNcMbu7/xyqcAHLEWfju1vMRY7RK@KGrPMPqKiOClkA2cYNGlFWXlWT6aOnm77A5iIX8NPYeUQqHUIwHlloh8QXqtNQDYGNk9LlI8UhOtL3vDyAQrQMdga7UZisITlG/DvEBf7ZL9r0RrGJVODwIooMIoWQZidHtf3j7YOjV0S5w0Zt73CnhpjBwGzJVpvRh2mwgei6ovFO1aNnALvfLn5bHMskN92vqPCvriMs/8IhJx4ANiikQb7TOcLycqafgefe8yKQRPGgQalotBVzDm5cu@qBicLYcxDyWuS5Fl2hyNO8npA6vNme0JWjVZR0REtDsfWwA4xNH@qRdS5PUi6@dbAy6SuH1HJRj@oSv1j8s27ZDH3rGfnIHpg4O6y0g37yy62WYtP5BmPqA0pF61AiQrL4CAU@80s/lh98b4rX9woc9KlL6nTTnt47VnMnlUXQHjntfpSO61OQOBZXR7p11UpSi0TK/NPTE6qjOqky3pcYT@2Sp3YJqXGByy6nFTK1fn45oYjNI4/qkueS68auZsbVE28pOdVcBxq93cNjh2gshEsdqjCsJjpywxhNyLonbpU9cVvxuCXOV@4eVsoEYSc1MtHhjPtPYTC320C2yMzYBu1cIetrYGH98xdducEX6in5RifXxCB44pQGqNMunCs@cQ/VvZyBmEAa0m6Zc5FcnToVD19EIGQJNz9Rn65BuzDFqICqg7QYb04TZSVV0rCFoejzRLEqemGr7TZyghx3ZlZ7ekMXAqEv33A43pXAt/HxhAropM9kVgg1cshYZ6UArqsmEhAhysc1SKcBcYtloOypzvxiFGaLIQrn6mQq3wGDok64JS4KEPQL2D3g6yZenltuXznczXAYOeorWLosdlC4O3pPD1lWymZ9238PzvZZPj/eHYznl7GVTHq85RhPMmP5YuBHjZONxxM4P2LDERWKbIU8g6Y76IKKpkEj5o@2il0/5o2bxUP@GJU95WqZW7C2EMeia7BZf2DjECV@aB7nax0mDaVkYAGEIo0Biy94up03AHYHsiXrjsL3WKIgFzO7mCBFRB1WsaBcTWgZuGwMJT5@fx66BUvhA8Dg0zZatEgScVA8qOlBn1YjxVFhuFYsPAZAdcRG/wWSOYIduGiociZwPV3hUHV5g5NQiARq0TjIwslI3TJSjw@9CFeG1JWTvTTl8mRPoi7N/RgwZoDIK1iFaMzdgQVB4JluhuzxZfFFNLdJesBj0T9vaHC2k@HGqWuHCzS8j5m1/NX6nMEY4q6Wvw8aikVMhIrKVI@6e@BIArhboFruOAQHosewTt0T4eLWKFIQ7Je2ysfCGckI0iKol6IuxUKuw1U64jQ7Cl7wPodO/FyB1hcVKwNGYsOctz1SQCDLRzmE2Bs5DYHtk0MM/TggF7yhLqfG6w@GiMPb74bimzjEtcLRHRV2ASLgdi2pXTz/fE/a/FKINkqJ8i1p0zmloKivLc8H40UWYFg6HxhkiuSRWygX7PRwvO/NBaTc04DUQ5mfSO2xmRfJzQBNUOKRWfcIcSfG6uYhhch941rhk1RiWY1QM331w5UkqETBCMSz1O7FUIWggSsVeO6avhhcZ3bjuJKEQsSm31mRI6A8x3LG3Q7sCnRvmHO8r3deQTknu0V1i0k1SJ8k11STusbJsopm4S9rQpot7KqvsO4u44nCikhuOWfPd9DB0dGMG37@AnYoQbFzOfhdO86@a@NkiPDx91EuNebJv8m9zr4G@aEybpFe@by80qZZ74W3VTF3iKLdz@8YD/Gm3UaO36SmLkBCcEMvu4vreayFBaHOgNIzES8TFcPOHju7KDodkNe0VB9PrN3LuJjGHENYKux7joe6oM@KNQHsgn0hOY8ZiHqwHRVK6oP1cZGQzBON1OUODIjFRH9WmRgNHm@gvpcR/ViE7PRtUX4wPsmU2VyMMIx3k/NxuFFEdz9u/2V/Rkb3ZgTJQXNEoq/z5oz4kQh3v@nM6Fh3M4XmBnqXmYHbJ6GICf0tl3b1gIg51hc864DbA37dQCjarjKIA1ugwINtzLdGxxmkfi/8@ISRT3yCD7fmQUw6AcQfjY6a8AsknsOMzywyfUbMbDapdoiiJq@TyXxTRdJAiIedF@OJeY7IUpkETgNyZ0yaKdUEOkabnGk0rswP/yBVFs8aJzvVf/oHVvwyFh6nLMd2lombg93VDoRC7ZuawnfuSHuN2sGud7QV6zmOWUqlFNtALztpWN3UjXqlpjhg4FgcW5VQBtjO8ZAqHtLYOoWuDA@ccpLsWOGLFVDvRbXsI5mTyiD6ESPhCVg6AHc6oPHqLQU/xOLc4PoBgcBO@jMLwbINerihs5FhNMe5l8XOHJ6BOOXdhsx3gTCDZhIykGrJjq2MlBRGTDU1uPVlPDc6BSZ5CkuYOtCVPYh9DE1CSV7K13Jg05cx2jk9lSodQxdI4NgRhTj4DXNaPYJjCA6ui2RNA@rGW58qjAQ6MtLQtRHT8QiALmC6RmiQKpAUct4NFJNW3IpJHVryoJAdsZIu5knY26KHo3jYfyeTEJaLBvj3d0u4v8M2kF0shdamUvSJNS1TazJ4w5xcRMHt/Em/Fh7O9fV1Gt4Sj1TKF9fQH7PuY94aDzr/C8h@38qPVAqHR01NHrHgjUwndrONldV0voS2ltrViQ2xteAhOj6NXRma@BVbXBiA/bgbV1OuFY1lsRrfqPYAAI@dARQpEDItuduXXcBItsQwGd8ZXWRfT@zoHwcZhjbp08F9E2xsUePONMakMTbawSV6FSSm8Bb9ghIFqQW3p7jk2TBMVgJHW2kOutQZ4L4sNwbujpLjTYwgR6uRZvQpPEvwhKxjlpahHWPjr3jnV@F6IkNl59DM68ydoAiWA1QKaPoVnvuyGx97DgTzzehAh81nNaBHWGYNYYzyUQKAxj4swuFsPu5Jk@cuSNvYPcBRG0qQLy52Q7CIpjjs8d41JcvMt6YERAKeN4WMSUdgpVLuyEi4ht8jdl/WwzyURo0i3D0eIuK93rJHDnf9QoevPlmjM8EYHeJJ5IyW3VX1UpnduYC4BgQ1HFxZkgi7KwdQw7Rwbma8IgVIH3StsIfQ@jKQ/QokVRyyGfZLvmLwBd51PtolVJDpYKnuzmGBfyVddqnBP1/u1f94MusJr80FKvgifQz9lgl1OtjiEzE0SyImmCbyip2X4BHiDo5LdPERzg/kMckNYjSRBk3j3oAqzygfcwVhgTpngrqUOBuyLo6@c/MpzkbiFU@kD/BDp9PxUUUqe6dUK/qgf4vGSJxHGZhxBL5jCkj7cgDvwqKzeOJe64ZegsQ6CvIACQr0Onf9cWjjNh1n0l2ZUm7RZ8m4iAc9Ypb3567FutARX@kcTBH6r/NuovRdOxjn6eGUATkk15Gpx8epcSJ6uR6OjKvIMD4C0cFwP1JVWB3oFoPz9DryBdEZJWKeRggYHIdtyDjv2EDaRdwTyFhjWAEDqTGq4BgeP/8LFV7eLOgAGYQvMQBMJBAQLFTmKrsUTmQG0TeMxTAcjLrJ8IFZQivbjT8TjrVH@Hl8P/678SF5RIfGMN4YRd11KRCjMVomEnjLU@5mikvZ@w3KO5PfqfLO0MMr7z308Mo7S88fVV5vxPgtFQS6GHqgjYMm@1OwqAHa8@TjFE8ZeqbHPdTmu@nYAxM/LjQVm74UMRvbME3DxjPN5@eApzknExTu84c0n/I0SuAGAznFh4@kQhqaHp7@bwd4E7cM1Bcj5MbPS/L@C/RJjY9tiz6aPBBzkUb0vdfE1DskEBVdid/LFYle@TApLlO5OgFq2xWtL64wX1JlL@NUUG6DMYrslT7K@KsPh6/otHwRcuNGQUJF2bwoA9Q7MN50FPSbH0VQXcjHyVhIdTY3lluJGFusrnQ1IRI7wV1uJY217qBvrqlB0hnY1adPeHasN947jLkMziuDRnrDMbeXBlNst0OjbRt8ITY7FKNTuO0JVHinZxmDbo/hQVGoAyIsX1LeMVC7R@0StHr8pugAz6opucviIuPie@PHKXZqMjDyaf88ttxXh2wDFf/mCMeS@VhAxNdNiBVWCwuu7rQwHtJeIEnvAdf5QB8fcRgnT3Xmy8Am8gNk4RWOxEHyR8ROcxJ2O7GE5GkgQdlx8AR91KxVXgQs/jiaidMw44ioAbhnfJGysuCBzs8sZ2Nfbil3/uzuAavMy216biZpG@p0JpsKDvWlH8gcH0WcHruB7GDqmJtN5R@h/rxU@ew12P1fYU1I1OXKOMEpYOTi4mhQdnBrXh8PIMeTNTinggUOKPcNC23DUXwu5hscj6PWJd@A7UWmMsLFkiI7PbBnr3Gh0dzYNOPWk6GqaOsAIoIckGrF585wvgw/5IaxX5E56kXmBrBNqhyeO8uzYbRwltmNPEsJy2gpSttGlVVGXqF8RnB7g2iu7ixhW5W7aCGCpe6KXjc7NB5N1mJPbfFdGRuHmBVL@TRQLW5sY26SUJe07gdYYaOntK4IFj9iNMaeUPUEkE13EkaH2Z8GsoVDDobFYmE7IGQ872mOxEqcaT1KCKjyBDBxXmVWCfEBo/qJR0FOsZU7XodDNa7Mo8U6@N2NsC2@eiHGjJC2/rEfHDVJMpBX3oAMdM@a2KGr2oTHZ37/v@0923IbyXXPwle0htrFgLhTlEQRHC4lkdplIokKRXntgrhYXAbkSAAGxgxEYCluxbmnkkqV440dO7ZTudhJJa9Jyo6rkoe8r//BX@A/cM6lu6dnMENS2vW6klq5vMR0nz59O919Tve5lER/OsC92B9XMA93wnhnzS9kLDtXHXZiGOum8RED4o01nmtglGooE43BpmNcnsS801wMfnsBGqvKAC4ztJaxjPHVgwZDGRu32PMOGQVF9xeQTffnNtJboGD6qGsxcaUIgWVqhRJVsoiWjuJFrCN/VDYxM9giYoBDsMJl58/5guZPIAM0wr0HNhg0f8cbxm4bLyup6VL6hJVOvURCll2BfWA4HYTtketPg8H8100IuSsUn1PyzpA0p8@vyc84O45iGEtnVQwGIHare6TuhroJKKjD5r3yYB1zrAO51eDEDX15zoqBNIMJSioUDz4T2QeY90Dm4eGodAISOegyAW96UE0gJBuvEqsNwNZJ5mKjsELllIJduxtOaRM99lG5AnVKp3gfhDoeEzQRoynBDRv7gsj9sTvhyoDa5v5UqPMZ6DVy9QkbZORr04NK5dFH@HFvxm4h3fNBAngQt4EKVQ6PXKMMbL/QcACnuyNotzreOq68o8DDjV@3MPom1kDVwl/E7bENXFThG9fGr3B454tVIu5EuRq6FYDFZtySsZ69fVXK9wUl6Cf0n4hlVnddCpYJSur240sCaVUsXsspAdZrkKKF7TmoqbGBFhawLgG06R1edfCthbU26O4MZ/EECMRtT7rH0CWYLw8JJpzQOPW8Hg0byHB47a1dmQcC0GO8ogIz0KPpsIMuafo0XtpMk9498JIcQOwIdYFqjkwvPdrhvCLQ8zNU9aT7415Bry2uiuQSFH4AUN8j4Qkq20T3l3Jg8DvSbNKj07flJ16FrOCw4HdTJqKbEumPfiFr5VB5rtci30ojibF@DsZCdHmWMAnDC6/QUHE68Scv@OUIr91o5w/bHt1741sgKyxjIXWjh4/8QZTHLxnqci4Ka0LrGQ@W43Z48SWvoqYQNsUBG/Sw4VQ0wPyG14iUlrU2co1pC7awLt9AVWUWakZxWX655I1dE496c@U7RLYNqpmmW3KsHXMp8FzLq0y2a5sM@pK7itGGhJQUgdCq5Xj9Lq8kVR1lQkNQ3HiWcajxRUeBNaS5U9lMOUPxn9uphk/SijvarKnVyPThOEwdUR1aSbhrqOouK/MG1ieLDT9FynV0AIc3GzfaMfg6tSFmUr@LLK1mrOF1JSF/C@5xE1nSK1fmrzM6NBZaTTy6k7eImuUyILlDKwOuMG0kpDy1MfZ56aeYqkglTw53AMe7wGAK0nwDPs3L8CAs6Od6uUCDsBKERDvGSV/m3QfoO23dtQeBL12Z0cHKhQJ6L3y9lxi1Arl6ue460z42BV/6oUxkoLJonXK1r7ccUs3lB38eKQInvcMp4uD1XzC0BZVDfbZaASgyWZEv/LJgU92JI3qpRt2Xd2TcA7HcktXKPigXRtgJevA23NmQVPXuxD2CP/setqgX5JFf0i/fldw2XyY@3tt9dLCz39rf@crO/pMdKkmK/NqgeDqu0k1ZcILOvUcSbz6IOcTJvT/x4BzHE4fiLKEE/qTrh6G4D@KuC@L4izaUbE/dXOab@8qD7LyngTtZ5/IHzMyT8T1pGgcemghNUVUJ@nfCAjg/D9tBgYkfzkBySIVarwP0ZMBxoXK4Z8Jmzjm4f@JK6vgUEZogpGUDHil@PzxBDlBKE/E3ZjhpBj1YzW5F6tgqaLxyiPwlaIcIyABAPmrdzisUldxcqzDwLvCcyEZiWznGMMje92riMVe7TdWKbe4X8pDtgT86yknvCUYLiHODQ6uEMc/X1RCTURBUgXoL6CkQR5p7xB2qonxQrVdq1c/PpUH0iP0b8lbwBib5b2jnvWinnxo/Kc1sX8UAMHics4QNXSxsUqoFXXq0prhBXaKiFVnRm5mTZ1uTS/TXf8MW5BkG5LJ1q1@M0fjna899aTPrz@xj4Ys3w0kl4JhVjiLfVBXTs8/PYOf/itXI65mLXGRF8aXpRLrphAyo9jrGE/nlPGkfI@exu8cX9njVpK9/AqXdLcMZJXgytWvFFG11BJu40nwUj0ZqIl9OiT6mQR9TK/@1qcNn9zXFFiDqbrra8Wv02jCOiHW09lqa8DpQzwUq7qa2/lms/apeU20fVdonc@Q9o4s0XHOyuXEVadptXr0SMTVwtnRhHV8if6lhrs1blFN54zJOKaPLs0PdmXHJhPo7XwqmlNZB3kIZI4vDa8VDzElqNW0SJVytEVOIl3JUQeE6Wxy/hNp6NILRZSk5ETMv8WVb7WUcGwxERWcD2h4UknMUQxldxmahjE@NmousyuRCW7AJ0S/w/1@srTQJsoHHl0ZWv0Ejqy@tRr60GvnSauQ8q5Glq9VpMKl2vFEVWLOBKJ8A959bggW1vSfef@/OgTh4b0fcf3rvt8XX9p6K9@88gpQ98fjp3Qe79wT8f@fRkx1BBfS/r7gTVLkXMPXbbtel2/mVWm1VEOaFAOWr4kl7KN7zu@5LIJ6NoD3cOuaPysgNN7nUzkt3Mvf5OWiMyiyhtJqguyJ@a1I3Tmhx3QFKHuI7ovLliW0kb54B3yyR7QWFQ9cG3Py2RzwI6XHRs5I22gB4H1IBTZufZEl3Gp/WiWnpVYQcOP3vtUcQmMKHT8SdR9sY6XN792B379ETcX9vHz4ffw3d7IjtXXQbc/cpZhHgw73t3fu79@5QAjegVhF4t0YG6@c1oYLgNCrdF/0phgcboFQov2JevZdyuZGvrCICkZ@OIvc9PSApfHdnZ6cNctFuX7uz/@5XkKtxvy4sC4NcGg7VpQXCtRoajUBtMop2g52pI2tZrvOGNJyLa5jdyNEdEP0uCYW8QO/Eniuse3iNiA/SFDebGTaFGiq6CrgRlXIE6wiKwJDPlzYI5SbURrcHqja8WO2rDyy6JR2zohy5pLy0BoQUgzPujrocRlclAN2zVjdVG04YAC@EZAID4B0MJoTtF@4uXpKIGxJiGqLgDwk3OeH5cHz/BLlGNHCVCXc5EMiabBPPG00pBjhqeyOex5hZE@8OFCOFigQEj05yBgN15UoqccD/yzc2fJUFSAt2wT6sbCVURM9uQA2wtx@3@2EgbKeAt8EggrgjjzW1jgZtEPfoXniCBksvUY2Aql1z8N@mclSvGE4KxKlEmM5cxNuhy23Lg9@9bDkoeXehRtTbo06jwpSM/3RhA@4uNOBN0ACisrlfoFuhcUiMLaHx@5KU7cAHigSRT3wcj2rk96ZdN1ZAyjr2c@@jjwpykEtREUPFh1qnNeww1AM@hJygDypycwFCDGlKHuNrFM@hHe9B9DY8RGWICTbwQzW4sjZTeFA1Sk0cWSny8xm1dtpkDHdhrUTxrBust6@x9hlFz98Bm@XRM0kHxWQtzQXozxmVGNCz0wTdvPQFKhbNQ2oJB3fIRXvHxyKoNj9Ycza37z4rf/xh6bBaPeJtod3jxwtWSuRnFhLJYXlo3UnSBlQrTSLNBdMOllb6jLxb4ipXyIBxOfaA@d5qNXQeX6supo8oXlY8nRJfvXK4VJnsTYiEMJJMtLuVRFNVWaIyh6IgEUR7JzQWPeuqlBLh1Pv1Fsa1x1lowIiMcB8h9RozrBrp1xjervFBD3aWnOTTeLo1/oKKRS4piv7Z5nxUP7DvOsXNQlVB0WLSw2mrLbqkMNcLsldnOL10Xi2g2z4fHezfl0e3dm7r@Hh4LWzb52J7rbaVi9m4@FgycF0e7cfnoOXD7Y3QQt9L2Yj5kFzEpildE2fp2pKi@Qtq/HBh7mjtARo8ezGiqkZq1DYdDdBDnM2X4tA0KlAw0UQM0ZOD7Z39fWHt4C3bOpSFfa896pJ9KW6DiPuq8nTEdsi02VU006TDBGnmSaWcsXlpvNrzFnPq4GVsFZIHKcnx0JuFjtoLkslMWkfwyUIsBBpe84aoRi7eulO1BwVNifisiZpQIpo0o4O51G4u8eHDTvZpk4nGrcS8cfDCG2tmxp1JZ110VT2Zm4gUI4zHQfsIX77T5@995o/XVT3MYLlfn1KHUQm/i/7yxROoeIwvxZX4DJ4zLWpKSWeFqHRJjR2Z5cU57M9OUDoW@5nkhY1tXTLHsmnMH18zItkRf7qF7/xzmdkdyvtOtcVTyoY5oYXo0LPjRxAwmSAGiy2TKqD44Zk8wmg09DnpaIbcXGvXqDVN1UqKZiZxN7KB3gIO/sbN5PaQrAp223OrKn8@VfEpEavJiLu1WIPKBMw3b9y4fhHuZC9U8fJnxc1nSHL/DIfjl20DZTAPSFUIKHf3UUnlRwRwztA5IAX2bLVgEgWB1Uk5U2J9p8PIbB@05WSCtnjQmL2nByW8L0rWWhCzRNvSsfOJZGInkIU@GEtYd5RXzcLon51f3V0K6nZBfVdfvz5ebAiE9@Fnv@Iwmfv@GLdKYMQnLfaKCiL5eoBacSGW4OCD2tOvEQNzS8WxbHK8uS1@4UYbaa5xK/RfoF6/ipwpY5tZ@AxVGbbHp6/wgusVXZlyHtoEyLJeSWw9Zx0Vjqy51fNJiaCvQ1lucSvjabDNv2yZwTfXUX2Q8hjAeMB09ADm384LkHvW8VZBhZrMFzkN@BOdVOYkoNUQZQ@dvszpaJfgjQdznV7l9J6Lged06obEctLWES/zmxIyGSEzb0lguqv1@vMWDbvOfoezgY3RSW/JxoBsOfB16lVORZ0qldSUZadR0iEngSSlk5YkFB5MXmjSUuC6L1o0yTLaHCDMl8TIGxxWpP7UO7aUHQvShCPkiYTy7qiXo0mhmKcalToSttC1rCSh5pZ3WCEFSrkBoUwWTSwvpC0vKmACQ7oR@pKJiotRA/C/shGyqSbxYs3NredI4RM36E5dsTNDGV/FRlRUSY5BlsTOo22xd1/s7z3eiaPGFreQR6FSSmGPQjHLhlF31JItwYT70/C4xYnqM5l74nKuQsHfGmjkTwwg/kzmqgoIxSEuS3H6qvdKNOHwHutJsXuFQznpqse6D5WuPx2Fp69mr2h6Z8DpVYAE3hFnFbwkeGdhWORKlBy2Igd6i8OwkMhXtpRbhagWSqFaZtI3hy8trhNrvnAmseX0/glTByuTNukoICdsk7gT@MjyrMv4ljAc3eMo4Ca9ZTvCtpMNw0OpUllILopbOnCja0bcjVd2yUqKWZXcjiphCtN4KgHGEY1qK4ieL155r1Rl0aGCR/9aUtrRo42@m@U0GkcMLbsYTO3QyOZXCaPPvVz818KCkzMo4vFG5esGLwgM8h7t5g7TeAyM6HsBTG8OCowX0AIcrYIYIC@TBUAqv4ixld7KaOmlFElvcbQeF5uTUUuELqVIei1Ro@NTEa31xGx0feDOOCAJ/miBIGicr6kzB2SzUHHWYhXJgpIUSZxpcZ02/ymk1KG2aYYAejxUP@uHbHoj8maxc@HjI2K2QHbeGBDcg8idCh5rZno9mW4eSWLTKJ6EMBqVAAaciZPq4rlgTyKxpBO01OJlRUZbMho48lryaIQt59AAJRLKAC3HQXnVRLAAiiDExeHJYoDySoyDFtNBDeIneBNroq3GatSgxXRQY30sYC2nYY2DFpOgC/sabZTxsdcM7bJ9/uQVMvhYE51RlTtzu9OQTxrltALWUAjLw2S0JHTPO/LCd0TEaNGvCrQHiXZ1TXrEVmkg4N@4pVkfKqBYbbMJstoIIe4WBi/lpVTM11Em@xYx5pp5jMFziGt8HzdAmwRhToNgD0yyIYrJkAKNOsUUK2YODZeahaJBxkjCEkun8HmG3G9z6ZTFHY78bpWswpnFzWrEdlHok0qW8tHGhhqLSui3PJH6ryEbTzj8sYjjqERJ5/yL4ZiGOhWvOEoDv8uXnSXE1VDCWhPSUQCnh50EDnxNWeyLKghoDi9uBz6oLOLAJhTFeZ0ycSihahHH8qVxKIFtEUf58u0geSqtL29dGgcLgmk4qpfGgRS4OKbW0ikgOOP/WmmkFhsPNIuSqe1SJ04aGmc79tVJ9kWJqgLtBQlDDH6W@Eprh2TMTVofGGLQpcYDhY7F8bA9XkmbcBTTzl3jC@Y6liwsrBcWbimVb2CNldcQ14KwBwdBpT/Q6ztl8SdE9MQliURI9x4oxFS6xxMQkXA2K1L6UAwI4YT2t1qomtVq0c3Q4/29d/fvPGw9uvMQhagl3qPw@ga1ZUhdp1ZZwXj2fNvSIp0iR6CqBXYjR/uwkUftk2h26BShyLFYaunUgDuzmIHCmhy6L6qM3BNxH7IoaP0CToSs6LsZmB6b2qA3dav80ipEkOYJpnol5bVNaAnBMJ3IlhCMkZwzhC0u/2zEGirPRs9CBuyIJttkBodme5@h4ZJRUIjyy2fhV9xJB3VJytppKc8iquCj7EbOqVDlQt6gRxiMCfxVtSruKqe40n6tPeiiy9tpnxzfDr1Be9jptSvj43GuHzjSPY2d7wfo5DKHylS7Bzv7T1qPMU7Xzj2ynMB/Dco72H24s/f0AHOeQNZ1mbyzv7@33yIF9f2njw/QY2giyTIBJZYITCbEgB7tvXfngQHD35ZsJBuEBCBvwh/pyqckvHFrRv@dk5lHiVUhWhSEh8xUsCillUToDV1/qoK3of8JdcCX0PIEH2WgLhXVmBzS2Hj9KfMiX6dnBhS1YzIdhwRKGvB2YiQK8RIMMwyOsAD5IgqAbydt@grfKGMeGvL5YztRFg1ksFhO2nf1A1oduEyezEddW6GTjjxLp@4IIPG1KT8N@@W1/FkBvUqOSWkoWThfhZOjSs5R8@kl5QhKrfScEcTIvHZt5JTBO0CRRQlNQmSZQgX4BbEhikWvcJozA0TJLNhVOX7UqTBs6OMwMn7NFWOO2K0p6/lC/Ugg@pe0wNE0wp@PzUcpIjD5PkXGHE20PNdjRn9VZ/mG2dazY9P7VGTXXUHtkXvQ4DuhzY5eyGdfRHfyuUs2oIUZyRmP5wF6@TYmO0wVMo0HYQMGKpzMBVsQBqEeLuj5If53Jl27dlGBxgaCK5iwlsW57I4SjYSCkAFIzLM2rfXIjQ2bJWjFYYbYMCHqaRAfmBAraRAvTYjraRCffsIgXt8uFtXkbYqVGzdYmzk2nynF/00XL5cV7IZShY4KAz6zuDqNGckO45DQRQfNQc0zG5CbLbt5bsviqD/9d8Bt4pKlylQJN/ycZp@D@ee/Z63zDd0lRumvuYfGBoXMiXzyYhNmvC@8J0lcNUnakiax/eQcbJalZjG97Hcjivggg2g@/WkMJp1svq3mXejxUy9cV6Ky9ciqIYngPxYROK@DoMXl1foib6NswIvZK@sai@pBhIBBrpsgK0mQtCpfnVtlzcRXT62yboLULlPlpz@TdcrzKwXihxqC9lo5mKmg/xVbaKSaD4XSQAOGRJuax9Grbyb4UbwNZrE08McRdipyeH67f/6NZLujkqnwv59KnFTApC817akD/w@XxXE9E8eHjKJczhy3PEMUi5kQn/4oagcPb3KZnbdIfv6HF5euZZf@3ah0dMxvqoObuQaFLLkFavWgeCYVbWpsPH8wADolpTXGMarXnLHk8CyWBmPxDtR1trQ4i2evqOx5avZ1nZ1AfsYMluKS0L8eMUYbHGGQWKPoN1n5MsOlMjcdk2srcIdMbpeZdWlgDmOjeRxpimMwPZsJgWM5JmQsopa5BcnsneWIC26kCj9Be9I@HrUxQGvgjyoyAojnV3eG/nMPD6pJFd1cVJ4HWdLQZ2GtCQHJcQ6Kr3dQoQKaKp2KsO43y@0I2O52p8PpAN/QHClXoWOkahVdxpEgOJoOA4kTT9y7U28APXCQU4tYRBDzxtBKOoWBlb5U9Ymq06pdrLJaZb3xCrmhoyRqW3fijUOqzFmUBdDlEzGoUIW3YcAqFh4N1E8JEbuidWR/Hngj1zbgMYqrVzISyC9C0eFSDaKM5JgYOEqoAfJoOoxhOJUzTroxDudUArT4sWulFRw5F@lGTFyMEKKtI7xArEgfdORaBpFIC6JJHMtKabXAo0SIHgN5DuMQq6WVGlY0xixyUUSeobVmebtPbovIqJVwEDYNTbMAHGGEXo7rZg16Bxm6XY71y7/95O@swmm1qtIopo43aoPMQBFJIqz4eeA/Vt8GepRPpK1iAvffR7gZdc/tesM2RqgJDdRAXBmYYQIR8ykQGjqt8gew3/hHtuELRlWIhFWt3tneFgfv7e@9j9ZQfIlAVJAojkSwLqwiDzuVjOVLxWAEkZSwCPNQVoxAqhGLULpXCKZ7TO51@rahgQWj9c0/ptGiu3wfNd15XSYQYrbFTn3wnhB1a020eiIUBeM8fPOPGLM/Zu3ZdMT@2JKECT/HLhC/uoq0F/rFEOn1/eL7f0bVSYsS4PnwXmVoVp3F9FNuU17IEs2W64eZvYpVQ4OQifjCIfrWjwlZwEG61UaYu2LuihpJerd/@FeCcODjA8yeUVLE8BQvRPRtRqRfD2jkMvGVL8T3HcbX8@gVwETUmce7@BDOycoEjYZsI7l6wfD94vuyxQDvhfhmck4dy7Hm5lIn41/NmaWycjqy5tfAnznDPzCRSjPXLIx8UKXi@eRn0TI1u8muk5m@rxirM9G01A5/8p9p1Ec65rB60AM4ozWnKnWtZLT5L/5S45/lrswuIJhf/u33fhT1cZbZs1lmf74XrabZYi9mWW2/ktiSvopHhlWcZU7FT@PVxFbuzDE@sxD8JGvcZ/HBnmUteSB9vehnFyz7LCTfVkj0gp9duOSzcH1H4Upd7MluZSz3WeYyV9gzFnoC/3JGM2Ex/ou5GGfnzXzmms8mi78h5MjwofHowrRUq5LDqRFruyHq9Bc98@LfzWRrzN0Pr9oixsUBjgrQodQUoz2Emm2YK/80GVP@jPmaKLUunS2oHhm11GUtIJq0B0FKVY7zudW1gkMH4l5KLZtvVknurFoduWx0Px33UOqg97shSR4Tev7D4AHpO@M3aC6B2wZxha1tyD1Bk5p8SC84wQL5IDryOaREDfQA3QNxg/5u6O6W65xC8saVJJaBzyzRFbpOR1EoUxCRkkSxfpgqVLCcmroQ/knvQCxddVi6wsGSfSQ/slHOhZv3t36kdyQ9Sn4cewJl8WKc/yingVSM6K2cPHZIni4btRP70oJUPFUdAZlH9z@bu0Wiumxe0gDLwvzdP9EHnRugLmsP@oMmr@TxH4Nj4sBknoDG/sk/CYFdWI62jMya/1RNfMA7VFbleJJdop6Man78BxaSdvogcXbjYiFLYsyUscTuI/H0yc6@2Ht68PjpAV7ImI4RtQyeLeix2M37Mgmw8UuCBVm2AWL@CouzRh6Tl1fyiisF6v6ffw@7z2iLjlWzjGE6t9wPYuXqqtw5Y0RTcekRkuOzUJ4vLaB1XLfsreOsyRECAXp3FOJ6DVz4IcH4YoIdPsuzjcmfTaZNqVtWzHguMfWfZ7eMy5jsywQ86nACnLrA@XNqX1LGF0MZdGU1x9c7J@01j/FDL5TLTwL9oikodrOZfuF7cnJS6WN4qunEq7gBuicK0DFcdXwEzMLIp0tNdJsNhOd1QbZF54XT7ovoV7nbHr1sB6gg884MVaKd22/P@W8u6454fDTkUBxvek8sBN32lualbgmQlTrdF6X@Sa8hM9gwWCuccCJyPxP1MQzUL2/c1xB@iPfsOqszeNH1B8TtWp0BHGRWVDX3UEHO1af8HntsGKMukefS@6kgptlmRQqBjwaUAz@Bq1LWxd6sOT@MFZ/p4jFtloAjYp6LlBWCMZ/1OChswIzzZ1GlqtrmTDqL1yZk@PqASiEKEtHMFUzMIhxzZqwUv4kvVJiGkPNYGlr@dB0qrcabv2AeHUUYQBNjGHDXrjY/eNZ8djgK3JPlw2L1qISOjhC6I80aaUzJZw//xtEfvByM/SCWNHKDkBVcaiqpeyypgWmFFV/kWCU0bqBZWuHGiwYNtQMdysQt@k5oe9JMlbRxjul522pa0Rhzw5qyMTjSnlIykGn48GSY2puIDg1EmK67pCLxpelCWe9P0J@Wgi3DmKMDmNEczQgxUEN8qcgYpuIs3ip8LeMEGHb2gZvoisqHqWgmsoxunsn5N5t/9bWb34d1kd56IljeFBNKYzMXNlxXLhf2iLnpGPMKLagutwfo8s/aGZF7GqU4WGgsV5VpCteDXZBBZ43J70rHE/ySOpJaKFjXHGVfMXd4WfK6UEOqNU2iV3jKV4Qgy/MGwhFEUoq5stjMLAaSLm8c9CyWVuzEaOSMGjnjIgw9y2jkoSyGgTxNtw2H6LStDecR4KuzRi@JhSJov8T4VOyKaLmq64z2HKICZWEIE4p01j1Mrb1pNNrYtBIIkBAXEPTcfns6CNdzyQ2vXtZfeo/ioVR7FH9JMuC9AgiMtuAGK5XZmsjkiwVepXvk9hJ@NXNWvVQr1el/Nf6/VVKJ6v/1xcRaHLIeT6yVEv/7tSQe4simi0X12ipuyLlfLYnxPDz2Ryu5JaHPbEFnNvoj5BfU5wG/Dwcjbzx2QwpzJI7cET5uY@BXz8cbC3T@hXF14PcLl/yLrCvkgp9iW8@DFiJqSUSV8VxY17YsGPfh2J@E4qOB11G/MUb5zVX1FcwDdCMVuC7xQAEwQfKZG/V9Dybz3XBvhPcSVfSYHPr8uzPwO9UhiPLuhFw5BrDmAcLzK5PpqEruptxRD5/FyQyh/QKadgzVQdd6LQBrYbfsAlJe4KJ7SuvZrN@3yHmLO@g9cZFxw9sjoSOp7PaI72gHxxZua0viETBh6@xuRfkw0V66aMRdkZePceUBx3MmjYG8EekLNd4xliVpZlioFC3f68n1n1WhB2goZRWILbMLdCL6YQSvVDllAVYMiZXAPmKQPmaM8ayIeoQhQl20LJGNKAohE6gd0aesNEqgiuT57JWAPcReKSta14ZpZZ6xvo7uPfGuzKkX9E7hoZ1UfW0dY3NQT3BAcZrk03B9DXPIQWUgMOIc@6Yx@1F0ZEsAkCeEAiECjz1Bjwyd56REipd1cHgg/VVUHl5PdNAl2oBivOD91cg9oigp4qTjcSiYnhcQAJasHn3kjeUQlWKk2pkeAatNa4Eiq3hBMHVv3FpbpQZRXCMF2vO7MdCVKmBG17JVatxxOBzoXtwOj8XAfekO2P8bN5tiv/CiJDqz5faJ1803C0Q6MJSxnsIo2LdLnLa9c//BnYOd7ZIo128gOBuoaljbGFzOLlI@GXBIMsIivHwrnZurTOR2UMpvVfMF2fQtc9iLZoMVAtizJijHje28Q8XkzRwjBpGph3tVScdb1LHdUFcblxs2ZTrBqAWWGly18peWLCRprGsJSTC2OUKZQnRowBdsPAtAmXsFjIDc3VoohGEoIaJca@NquazX1Dr9KsPGWi5vsp25dQ/k8Bcivz8dxXbbPK2dtsjDJofe8nhru5qnfaFiNcSxk38ryDeQO9ec00t7WjhVIf5GfWyFzQN34N@dq/mzp0prBQak0KwfFgoyIf8//w1i31lkFjCww8Ip8tcfOcolbIU39R32oGnn@TYYin1UCd1ZeI8219AJG7pAx@/NKxSStHcPzt6e/ZFZx9gunJJ2c9dxrhdOocrJGO1QxrAZugeAsdDAtH4sLRI5nj0boVvcZZS/vvrwwXsw5fvoXyoImx8cLl@rlvJ5OOJJA8nBSB9ie@/hY7xJmBQqdKNwf@IP5bhM2rqSCj7so@Uwtb5kYdequAph5zxyQ9n74O78oH30qD0EibkNQxC/wGmbWj8Y5h51@c0xcqz45FqF0yOHoI4nbr/BnNBZ4Ly0jwqNEP4cm1XcgCqclRXCHkIhBx0IJEbdG8Fp/d7BwwdOfqMtEKuTsiryxY4mDiAUIhgbk0igjZEOhtNFqgrZbpMIBv4V89ZmvC8b1fZmvnF2ltmeB367xx6/8hEB9@xpSVLcxFmc0sYkooL52HUwgY@2d3cOrBKURdkXEynG0Zw2LXZG7Kg6mNxwp6AjcP4EYRxn9e23KQ2LTAPHWanVCqgecgbYyAcEoOWFNWmcTdpOz9YD2R57Fbo6d2dcFzEnK5WVansUnAA7Wq3frN2@XnvHn@C7Qc8Num8HsIU4bQwp64Xzt9GQn9TJjvxB/@2@N8AHq6ury2t73t3f@ertJze37W7nt4CHtJ4HPj7gT8ZmAybtE6n9B3vspMvURY0YAc5uuzpuv/Crq71ad622Vr/Vc2/dcNdq19e6N9zrtzu3b9/u9lfXOr3bt9q3bnQ7VXQbTUUqQ1IetJj8sdr@5arNYszWVmq3@/16/eat3o3b/dsrtevXVztrN3q11dX@Wr19/frN3spa53bnfK4tak8ONli17@LZkdyB38pm7nILe7ssXfhf';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_ ){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le._e _=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Numun Cr Uu8 gutyIO 0; nd e 4X
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212]!!(l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 39);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

Silberjoder is a meld of [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck) and [Aubergine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Aubergine). I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/quintopia/Silberjoder/blob/master/silberjoder.py).

This method is used to polyglot Silberjoder with SMBF:

```
<=oC<=oC<.612
```

`=oC` is print command in Silberjoder, `<` and `.` work the same in Silberjoder and SMBF. So Silberjoder prints `216`, SMBF prints `6`.

Code in polyglot is on line 10: `+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]` (was `+<[<<._>>>-]`).

Also changed SMBF/Silberjoder data at the end of polyglot: `612#`. I don't know why `68` was there, removed (`686#` → `612#`).

First three `<`:

```
...612#␊
     ^  ^
```

*Update:* [Some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167992#comment405983_167992) Haskell [improvements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/168279#comment406769_168279) thanks to Ørjan Johansen.

Comment: Just realized `data D a=D a;` is unnecessary, `D` can be replaced by `B`.

Answer (score 9):

## 288. [Pascal (GNU)](http://www.gnu-pascal.de), 13500 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                 @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      # ????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 (   *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa











































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu91&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pext sepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在e*nr""; 16 ""6int 21*F ;#4, _._#a *een ~>/gi=[]puts gR 8e*n 82
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
.exit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";   print(85) #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;@,,,"285_";# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 :  Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dc@NKdiD4XJj9B/uSAnWLpEiABCVSFClSpVJJ9@reqpK6pLp1u0leFgiCJEokwAJAiSyVKrp7dnvdtnfW09PjaLc9vu2e9ay9nojxTuys2zv2TIT9OuGYJ/@A8sfGhmPD/Q96zzmZAEGKlFTddsQ@LCQC@Xky8@TJkye/TrZ0r/ezn8XwYcdOf9LtOz7zTc9nbdc6N12VPZywB7rl5XPrkoShdt3uaGDavleSYkxjzDYv2KFtWG1wY75zZtrWG9MFvxxjj8z@28FbnxnOYKDbbY8NXcv2yXedsWMdLJ2Rccb0lue7uuFbjg1eG4w9t/v6oNXWGQUfuiaPlGcAyjijOLM@BcaeOK5nQgqOYXqeg46bjG2bg6E/qYKlCCF013Ie7z79eC7yFmMf65DDYd8cz@VFy7IXlum252JoGvv89OBg3jXHPlMcmx1cz5@2zp67nt7X5@FvsN2R7xz68@55tts1bZ3l1C01N@9ZYA9d/VqUTeaaertj9U3VYArrmf2h6TK0o28Rask3@8VsMTsTkdfqseu0R4Zld5nfMyHvw5FPMT3JgISqbChoQ0UDi1FKPBjAPnEGZrS8HhCF2Wbe0DSsjmUQIGaOfdP2IEVPZRbg58Lq91nb7EOEKXQjzTyHjbyIU6uv91RDlTqOyzAVNjjrM4sZwyHjXqxvQZYOskVmDpxXFnsD/v2ex8bDAfOsAXj7htPpmCZ7Yw57EJ0N2syYGKwFOJTajsTgMYZzRQxtqyaEsRGFe8dfZ13T94AG7Q7ksc1akXCQIco8FV23HcCjy2wdMIM5N4aToCbCGB3HUdG97ZieHffZheOesZZp6Fh@TMwzux191IcUrQ7Wiwvl99jAga/f020G2YLIPiIFYWNi0sKCYDJBPZtDaAVYzw62Faj0oLovXH0IBOOJCvWtgQkJ@3GPmbpnIUuAKJ5pt4lEhiGzcKC00dpn5xZQOaBi5BJsz3SR0FSCy7AUAFLHxLuuPmCJC9fygTSwFLvs2NRdduqaZhKL6DPTM/Qh5GMmSUjMwRR8LIhKFLq9Hd8/OogDpfIYqj4EynTXT7/2qaQztcJWm2X4VWS5LO0/fcQuV@to5gwJqHnoJvQkq7xjXqZeN@E31lqZrnslAVQJsNJnGWfoZ3RlCBlUfMhgRkcjmpTznDrsRxJm23N1EGk/PFQbagPaI/s8TSUzRq6L7HOKVP0MCt137C7gEwrrjmxe5YUsVAHQX9tLM/PcRBrgdeRcEIZPe0Ah8A9BI42cc3RCKPB0aJMCo0G6ntMfUTiI6fnYMAErEBUhHnbY56yjW32MAv4IiufaNT0gTowzsttY8wPLNtsqC7JhOG0MNHDOITkdgJIDtIZBhMlQpizqGRwqKnq9/7XfbHe7AGfXMBy3Lcj1cyB2g/oenTILPQpDgnVsvU/ZgnBpTJ1HhwTO9b7V1n1M3p6IJCgTlOqFM@q3GTXUCwuaXE8/BzYFnMLwTU7kzsiHPKbZQD/jrNHilAsFH@gtqFhKgNKmYivswR7UkgHNnGhGGYz8TpEpw30W9zJfJnZKiZ2VugmZS6rJtdVMplsGglPXyAls8Zso5/PdGXb/OesCoYyGWL52GoiA2c6FIBxNWUcyIc4D6LLc2fZqjk1j5JtYu8D3W1SSgT6hyBH2kicYwHpOD4@wiqAe3b6jt0Udv0A68S6Au/ZYSweO7iPnRjxFc4rxIW895C22xzqu@XoEWQKeBDia@D3HzjHFYLJRcSBAIj5T/Hg67rbiSRV7m0SybFUMtWPZ7UR8G5pRFXAWT5aNilGzSo3yXPRoHgDMBYJBTmMmjKSMre/UcpAP9Yc97K0hqO0NgYm6WFJDB3LwsLvyQQhKsxYRKvVxwCqIyV2YccBTS/dCwqA2xtsQxleQ8wkI0zYx2zTNdqRlQqsGBPveNfbady4gQcoTVijwAhsT1bsgP0FkXpBdXhCeErnMFukMqMNGaC2TFZWWBVSN7QeYtCDiSNkg@HqOhwFonOojNYqkAt0U7/SnLQBrWmcDaO/uhBkmMhHgJibvITCRETUoDyRF5nRYVsnl87ON5lqb8d3MrvIN4LpvMjc2DSx8tHUg52AdEEz7ut0d6V1oEo4NUXTDMIe@4DxQEs8H3jLfgZCjInpD1etJqw/m06ZeIRB8pmlQ@6HaE32bjuxCCL9KH7gj04X0zNrQKA1qBrOpQ4DzucTllxhkJgMv5SVZCLp0IDLeyqFxAwFf9CxopReUO5szOt6rzCcPTtHUgVUrnTBpzIxWvZ@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@6ZaVl2acah7xh6n5xXMbgcxH18@PDZ7rOvNxfA6Fut0rxDxtooFrB7GI2Vrj3KbKi50moUxhTwo@bNsDHibBhZEt5MccaR0erEAKY4xrGQQKgzQFmBvSB5HAdYD12QL3CqReJyGolp@kIxLZTQaDgVj6uvHMtOXMZXVlbipXgV5K@VlR0wbaNpB00pMO2QSSEThlPRRDHSZELfGsVAt0b8qhZAHicbyFzHOGZ8Yw0Teq1UWm@k9Zomvjn8JqHVgvwBoRX8AJx4slJBYzIpVy@goGqrM1v6PZShTgzXGgokfKqf69wusLBOaAA2gPXhmmUk4ptxMqi4QFgwVjR6CTder2XrjfplvZ2qX8XTGDtZ1itAQwlILzFQu64zGiayydpGSdEayWRtHWTbViWeja8lEkUFRvkwUE1@VEymdI7tRNwE2SpRr8cBqQI/NaPnErxxOpdMhqiCfKD4DEOxRFy9LEL6rWQjmYpD3GQ8DSP7SjwOmDEQCR4VGlnJDIKOnn3GEbOXSklEfY57hr9rwhm44ZzIbPTj0Zs32Cg5jFZIYf2RzgfYQxEgc2gHYVX0nJvTCLxaHYa98kwaHzsdPmjew9f@44Og9Xx8dLD/rELJ9HTvDCRUpYthM54P8pnutlVgTP1R25QWhYFOCEzGNCc4x4SJdw0D2hajYIrBMxERPgy2BBr0XDjHojpM6Q9mi@D1IL97M2UgIOROMW@Sho0gSzz4wjyFSR5A/7938nhmunJwBtIpM7w@ziYpLi8AWDNr3LFNnxj0L7rnWO0SO6QhvA3DFaAtGK20w6ki27EV7FmD0b4TTYjPl0EIckPZHeVSayYMAu5YY7ONctOEhGkc0QIJQY8ACLM9p2@qL6i3kBn0OgzFJVVaNLY85mK5anjT1gnDRzAO@7oBfeIsuLrM6gAQOFAms9gnWb4GGIaaMyNNmua5rYwgmBu6jfhrWzSNMbK8HqIXRqYoU7gdwCrOYeDgnLB2yAwYM3UB0@bYEp07tPATjPKJ7iWSOLjf5aNWpDIccWGmghleGg45hjFyTRh5oS@fTWP79rnlOjYiWd0H0MCKylgHc8AXoRfIaHf3MPdoOX4XAQeMXXPWIriNQp1HruFB67KdvtN12BoEQNJUVU7Yh7YBWQApyNeH0KKsN4Sg3a5jT@Zo0MThkodjbK2wjiTPp/owZIbCq6@gF2CLCz0NsKTMJ4ff2AfxR8tns5D/wJalJyxkBMp8GdHRYNMAYhWmj3SDNfkNc9ibuDPk5DliWs2nuWVqmHyiU4cBCeRKtPA3FDXayLkLtPPAqx2YFpV9n0aYOLc7nCwp/Yw0x5sNlDA254yuASpmgF6r8Gn9IuOqZ2b4VlB150pn4Ph65nMVWDS@JBxvKRaTvUx8JZ5RFHzL5MVyVZZpm@cZ5FJTyON9nPpaAHtsmkYGfbFzY4FhIXoCzyWoqcNj0wuKyb8BDsKY8@XvplLI2Cl3YdqU6Sc49/Cp07PjnlixAv7Q7uPcgNs1@VqOumjA@cpw@no3Q3Gg@@33MxpOIR0e4TKMtygGyM7exOQxwrmxCdNdaEf9gYMzQbgYaIFwzBIcPE0F9a1uzwe2Y5vQ1oCHBCi9oKTbMHY2DWFTXtkGdZJkg/5KfCMViS3pnpYrkgEaVG4DajQIPlOp0zgrHRM4HUhGiI7knJXV79fvswn0rAhxGbAYU9dopQZnvX2rz7CXAyg0uxMgizg3Tpci3yacvR7h/DR0Ipl8dmNTK@QznA6A5Sod1xkoA903eorvKABPcTo0WxTkPO5lOh50EB11TRiCTMNo9iMo@nrtSyCfBgxu6/cpb9jIa5NGDSTIMrseZU2ET5Yz8cXFRAki8ACCCytFtBCQKE97I1MyjZ7D5Prqg5nYMkgjPaABBZo5jF1xVBVGE0vCku@MjB6u/1kDyz@khcS@jdMuKkkKKnaRwncPOrcpgGPL9CUxVzqVaHCxbyoQ2V0e/hmIDQQVaFLlxOaa7czaFNoTx3F7ODGt0XRoLiTKgfDION6wrfpjAMBj7fNxZiBUPj16tM8HY5mR59Jwzob8NgdOewRNji15MG@4WrEPjMqynYEFJQpAvjnrP3Mcn0uquJp5tyeGEZeNFLn4aA1GfZ3GoPPDxBDGCYW5EYzhtJw@jVSXQQJJ9ujh0eMAyqfPHx/uNh/tHx@dRsC8GvUtXRtnhmfdZQX6FIMwTc0uGJWPaDl9buS9@/mTw6fHz09PKrJaigTL6OcDmdffUb89u1ZN03Qzs6iie8Q5pzIDxscUBd4KuvGc46yUih44qEOBTlFwWUvHhTuX5bTs1la7pReLZqFtbGxsdvROu72R04r5TjGfy2fhtVnYMtlbCq4o5phmrsHEZ4VxAh3TAAzQR1M3Apl81EK22p8szFfoe0PmjHze3NzY0reMra0tPbfZXtdzxU3TLGx2NrJZs6BlO62iVly/MXORbOBgYGob0Aw4NF2cLCVP6K4T8JlpUzzzMDq5YO1cLlcw8p2t9VwbOGO7tZXNF9stbVNvbZnZzsa6ltPaRk4rBXFBKgDukulBheE4yIbBVOClaOCZlALxL1rFwGHDqXdPcK3VdeRTw2ATCg51hccGeozEFhSAGbjn0T3YgIJT1MK9gO4D3H4yHXuRNXQUAYsUEHehqG4rcNxCx3D/SWQZgzp30eMv8l8eSUC@1LJXCJwz8mn5LjWN3M/9TmfGOUfOZwoKX/2p8zo58/0rM0kFhb3mtTBwCG@D4PF9LwvhXfNaGDiEt0nwpptfpj55nhLupFmc0JzPoqAhsAIBw503C2HNeSwIGEIqEqRwP05zIbyF3ksjcao/hQHBYweGcY8tXIzszDQDKZwIqktyMJs1OzuOPlyEzpzPTTAo53I0Hm/Qln3m0HRNaGpmVS2PjTSMPTjrX4/ZgQEuvWaChnkIxOklufMGrQ69FgTA3nd@dYE8aOlGyADQ5@qZZ/TBRZxFOZhdjppJvmV2RjD2xplfNN8STNkqUshOq2UtCwqYwK1RwXdBsBJ7NmpNWE7dULVgsgWXf4Hv8rUkkNgpYEunqYPZNUw2g3x/5PoQS3z/yzfbUAnXq6inT0iODQ1NENyxupTO0hoTUdFCr8W1O@3@CTFkug2koeM@EL0fGhaDptpXlJ7uDnCgL6obCBRfQAk30BrPOZ8BDL6LEyEUz66UMtsaMGNZ2LlFXZ4UTezgfgpCAp9@sUyK5GJV80owx3wiIiKyQN9xh0wFa69sunsJRnD@iL9xw9JtlWgN8XdTAxUhs3m9pZkgKesty7yhyl39bNR2FBD4qMiYscKCsNPS0wSx0unrZ9zYROPi4vMCula3CxKB@C4LdtGD8TSNkTIX9LmNKjx75A2VFlSWD82GbNQQBjek4Pb5e1kQS@yZDQ3LsWb16XVHShTQgVDE6lQGt1sqEaRZc2ju660JTg/1PpzKMEESUYDjVIxUKruOXVe4eyW6O3J5fOzvKP7W1uLYfKMnR8miUVaGb/BU@KIFlVls@bylYqHbsgZ6X8m1I8al/DxYrpiaFgSluULF6OsekJYvqsM8x5mC84V1OK0H7JcMGH25U9MNxD7NTrCJadl@GNGBiFZtOH3Lw6bdX8Y/57cQTNPErbb0iiyDWIsQ2yZhzOspoWkxX3AMHzejLCG0O3A5vg8Ed9pEKEd1liHNcC7wt1Sw6DnnJn8v7ubeLMzVHTiW0ieSsIyFfXvbuLbDGpx4r04z/B4I8UBMNM@v0ZCVb7wKdhrlC8PX12sBtzXSazHyzxYWxjf6C91nG04wPRIdl92xMXhW3/HYCb1vwiUUzPP4e3EziKLd0m2FFi6j5sXRRKaGTBXLAUuIQe93nX6h2M3o8FpKMSO3gx2J@N6VZYYsT9NuZ3mBSOXYmvgu7SvOMu7ZbXVHa2gu7lWKGG/othfxPbF6vryAQKK4AXFx4Q6yRYqpZvgweVkFuEbvQp8E35@jO1qG3aA7Gk5IRAeJESNsFcHgu1xs/3lS27g5tfbdeNo1sJu3FSJSuWd9E3o/el@rUpbLah8YQ8tm787hOv2ROTIXMrij1isTD8XcMHC5e6ayohirYqYUJ4JwnjQM9UYMOe@Ua@z40XYjgwFmC438VvFoIb8bgmA/xEH5MRiO0XA9YtceDWcqd2bgZz@7GXO9YdCynfZMJtHnQzlS8XYhbEb690z63Tge4@NHXIStbGSzWSEURea@Zyw3jdPWw7ivLP6eSZhcpilPw2LP6UaMi9OYzqBC1VtnnoJzmXfjTrllkwgUeGsrY1u26U/wfUdG23Kc/ofUHvDbtoXyHkixuDh5Wy1ek6XE/lc2nSnxcJ6l1Vk2R8L7IjGaBcThMP0mQohOtt6phhUUbqCBduesN88aRaZub0sFeniaiuLbe/rLBVUx/6KpRXXzxsbIxV@nZfZ1/hkXNm6Ct6Wu3wgvlFaEXE1LYriMxhfOpqv@sTmWNZwAsqw2DIp65sAk6w2jCb39auQFn6WBxg7@FnirtCa@LN7QAh5h43tmkS4iRfmODcM4H9eqcRzUx50bwnUZXw7m0Rci93Cgd01@DvMmxjmdGsHDEnz0ODUuniQp8Z2RBkTj25NuJgVoTGfmxAu@CwE@mRhQn6PB7RN7c@3eoM10tzV0NbNw@eAWMdHuOT27Z/b4brXQtqx5AEX6/ATtTYWA/Hd7BiP@FN1JF8Vs3@n374JZ5I@cWzpOZ2Ge9vHMaRuifhDcid4CD/G5dcIQunlCEPX3y9pNzxxBb@U5vjM0FbItC9rHySX@XsZFg@Wcn3fW6sYZBcBI8P154Ru3Rezqjj8c0qc57I88elFUhY4K3zBk47PllCTRJXPcrvrGGbRU4age8O8TqPAlzKaFR9Zw8xynbLPrtIyedVumW6bu29ZZJphj4tYbh73DCJ4spjxCZ7VvAXrdiYr0Uon6n@DncFmli@kq3rGFhsVUUGJ7I9edIKX7jsM83DyIUwa0GXB6tn/KVWY3a4STxXyFAw3LciVWEBd4kwyBe0aDvZE3LLOIBcelZElSO0roipkFMUdbOm81s3E50qbW1/lrmTQ1V37KVGSd90MmXsUeC5qCtCLzw@A@Q1Mzi9YLuzi7N@p615kkXxZog2CGr4W1v9tFzQl3qHxe0dCX6bb4LKuDXD@DR1/g24TaHJk3rurkb1zWoXBaX9EdCz5N@EC9jpZO2PWtocffTOksXREU2zxg5D6/bMmxNlk89BZV1jY7fBEGTbeJjAPHxfOXIJsohmt6Bs7hI2vnghhnY7bTBRav9Nk0cBB2ofB0fcF7IUWEXafyxVOzq@Ne4scWbivuLyAUgDq/un0b0K@NdM/62sjxzWWEhzoT@LqnGz2TiLYF8J7oXcv4ZAb1AbQApWLHKf/MNAV0uo79i57l0dm3wHDDxBUSGSdbpLMmjBwWDfnmFgpCdRE3z81ERC5x0oEphyw4EREacKkC/fWFaS1aA3CGNPickOmm6X/Lp@ld8V1IVou3ENyU/MVoMBx54rM4ddrjE50cH5yRu3dhAatUXgOHZj297y@eQI9M74L0JjrTqXGZPP8Nq@902TeKWQbCHghvKN4vILiH0K0f6z40CXsBBVPad1yixZkThXNJ7zXQhLnOFMu2/JtniXxfh9FW8MXC8A4IT3BnHuNbffChEJTTxRh5fPtoYXqs7eZOywCaOyF9HWgMVYZEqVykau4FqxKif7HNi@g478bFJehSHXvkK@7IvrH/KNzYf5TYuFiIkAFLfG3/yfNklBpoY/dt0qsJw8eR159MTUs3N8wRmWWDALec8c6GDsYgj0zS5fKMdoXeEmd3iKdMib8/chaNk44nrunfeaAFvcVo8Mg0cH3z1rSfOk9AdIN@awgMdvDM5IdIZ/jG4ogY7TGeiAT8tG9N5oTALugXpkNyfWi2oH77U9NiWWwR4Ee6ry/pwmimkcaNoelWWrH6LdN9RVOIEfOyofBshj4xxzQmWU4wvA0qvmFwgRsn82bayPxikDd0HJu/ieFm4aM9uZmxQFdAr7uv66u4WXqmp1s4tJst7VGoJIQfcF5WXNdsOX3@xiIsYQe2xbcw6K5lepnHeESW3AobTAFRbfHgh@8azqqbpKgJGlKwehpuJ8Y9cOK88NwIC0Tgc92jzQWLxzUzW5fvvnupp7uGgwtuwvCBy22RA4@3cPJwbzbfBNGCihkDU9ONkTg6d1tW@4PWgF5LxyWR2n5mtvBAaYtOkPv6eJEUOnswUjjOHU0M2Bo2/gJLHMPIJ3l79zY/bJvFuDWkFzH1i4WEEiT31DKNN3ryTkOmSIui2eiMTqPbhY1qdtMdiDd9U/F7rgkitH/TNHlwin/BWstoYOLy9uwiz1JScrwe0YGzeEE/ZLWuKTZ34x5EaPSBGfmtsruUUBE8/B89/DQDXXKzsBEcYgdGdvsWAsj8yLXF5y7Edux4fscaH0G@dd9xl3EWLFYeosCHNwI0rS0rBNSePerzmY5uZMfYoE3DOJD5Og6Y@sS8fVMx7XOFtLqNr5fIcUkxVWYX9Q/6ZlsRcx@4YqE8Dk4XhMHEd8EybZRN4h5VLcMROy5siF2ri5B74YULjuChDD36Zobe8eHjo1N16GmLZwt6qMvvmlQ3czAyV8xGJrZe6W5kVZVvpMODq5mHJ5qy9/hQxQBL8M1XRhT44KrfzGf5PoxhT2@Zvp7Rl46G0Nf0F4uLn5w@eZyaHuRnib2e6wzMZNR77@QkDdyGfXqy0Dsa@wBaR8cZL41@uK9pyQXk@9ymlcdljHJBSssgnZowpgVi/ISfKb9V1DKcodk@nQzNz6EfRWbt3TH5wtJCPtXPrS62Qra1FFHUUNmWWthIRjaWw5DddMPvsvo8s4bILQ36ZPhn6aYXFCLWM@76YkHipn0F8wINy4r9Dh8WSctep1bfUqBldHtoyujeL5oxTdOW4flE70C9svzSypoNsEjI6Dvnd1iVNsVQRgmdFB@oSrFu3QG/qQyAdWfwhZP8whGMraWbbW4CEDoXFjb4C9Oe6LbCFU3cIESUIDbwzJuDfMO8w7JWuI/onG0VF68ZhocBWMIgY/KWhE/dSJS9vYeHt0V4JnB5c6iPnz5nx7qHh3NvCCjOT5LayVCfmZcWx8jBzXKF4iNPDXSoijP3JGQGZ@nAUTeMEc6JA7NQGQVMJPRUKpmURKxPQNwaoIJGjOSR6gho/mWWDYyYyx70oRQeVTEl2KrOtisQIpksc51m0H9Avzgyy6xjBYChH7a6NmQgSJ/0S6JAx/UKeawPvVYAtVZjq5fjUrakXaGao5LMGg2eX3wokf3xkJRDPuPRa6t6o7IaV5T4arxul1g2HgY3@565OLg@ExYyix@R4RC7XHGsQ1pfQ1yWuSo@EJ1Rb6U43i16FSi/yxXK8RPZp3i0489/ry3UeZLa2oHl6X1ACKrmhQ6u51zs8HQDdA2Huku6GUlhXJ/rslP2doWWR67FEyrr@cFpUagSFHqAwXLMF03CXHC6wf0eqMjC52TBcxMqJRAJh7GCQhlOfzSwYdDW9nueyk4s0lExcqdn@Oi0Oda5i4u67TQ7ZG0T99GT6hHaw9B3nLNQjP/z3@MKFEkBiVAMESRPmlAjKaKeEY20FhqGM4JcB0DemK4jgiQQybrhj3CzECniJfckquUgzY5A60qg15CS4coN93ZPmLLP4qieC7Vrla1OYnX32cef17KNyjs2yJj/5ZuZ5KVAnPwRsDhPTrMgSPkKCSvqnQfvqW@cyatjmScYamexxEzRhVC/3WY6JzJxdJ1ozHGGQbPBqQfSrRpSo1BxlkAz1XOw7XhA6kaJYM0LOgJPJ7NtOuqOZg8aGFiTBJq3uspqYsQ3sSgnPstDgqgkUufqRh1UL2wNTFTWh1FWx@wtIwEVekQtnwUbR2Qf9UMOKiFbXY8edcs8MlsjOgFynlNz@QoVZ7VZ2a6SCUY4DiperX1ZH@eySn28ud/IeAFS6/XxR9ncF4B1x4VY9zPY8vafPrpcVavZt289fcJk@Spe5qf5gE2sXh4fHu@fnO6ePj@BWrgKGNsBP3Ub8BqkIlL90HP6pNIW8ILTGh/Af0LblAmihvJkUoqem6agAteyIq9yY4Q1zcS@Jfqi@J4Z8b8eQPA06KmlsF8AKtCJ2BBrWHiuuJaJuEIXKVGZhb0HNqAQMXhmcgEvJVTJrALIUgBZd0QVW17YHe52F4zdCuVmtO0sDIIYC9Orhf68iAtRcPUPUu6h7nm/eLk5lJvLTWFuKDcEDV2DOAe7h4@fP9ufjRZ08sR1K1t5oTCAM2dsaXyCJFC@Suo5RETcBFSRmUwRuFV0Zlynu@lfmFAswRyNAY9MFEr5l6UpYQJmKqjDvyGkkESCcoDSDQoi8/oMOtY4ksWgj46Au@RFDJnAgRyCDjKuygJyjPTkq/gExUCoAl1B0zsmJi74ddyLij/poMVh0bCPHnm8zS3pqsJex2PwH@mVAlOuwcZMdGdagyksB7@@aXehwEHYZJn3UWyVI0Je5XmXw/yiWnPIU/uVTsvlNL0gjvBDL93Xh14gCsbYU8c3S@z1yCHFVgEzCeUL0qiv8@sIqGq5bn1SmAWjcBB8g36L4B0enFRQOuOiGfH3KM2NbOyoIBC/EEBoA/FdvKWCa1jgmrk5yh2hMzroKmkG2hM6YkMpwWPnlmfBkJwqoYMyTh84JZZGFBzvcCCVZmy374FM0kY1lq2Jj10tCCcqnSrnR8sVm8kxoEk1FBnTTJYwrFe5rkMYutILnCN4ySOvUjiC7EVgxrdXFAUw17Vs5tkwDjf9EnsFDR0nX0vMd0e4v7savxYlyEKJTErPH/QjAReoR6@bmfe/9ptcJXrdB/N3hXmcfQi2XxG2Dph/NfDRNLD989CWA9v3uO3LDFbZdbXR03xGM4uNXZSOZzKsRqzCzw@PmWegXnSspIE@juAfWUcw9mDWAGr7nCoPg/MUpnUzhZOofQ51DwQDFY9yC4oqx/xulEYCtQiVMhkU63FhXKXN8@aY71mb0yZUyBc2tAxkUjkPAJKmuS4eAOYAk8kSMDvp3BpWXrYMtr29zWQc/pmVQplXemZV/3JdfhlmdBXCSnwEUGMQB6JMY4BfVURLrOopLYlRsYeKa3FkVm2H0xCIeQkyQJAkOtuBuiCQIx2BKhMVs459EoUmwcgGOLHtRPTQB4AUAMRhcw3us@1seqgXV3ciLU@NVoP8AoOdYLCSvIgKa1@yul@3G0I3PwOK@tECmrTB/MsLFPZzykLde9cVyyfm1cJjadiDE9vBhbIDyC1L5DK59YxWSEYoVBagIL/Yht8CSGi1wAUM03rlDL3dvf3DT4@OT66phKSQ8flgcRavbqfqipquNUJDPMz3LFIfHmROnjw8CFAZzdV0WghDTE8szGdzUWrzOV2S@gt@fvp62uRxLSEte1fAtB1YOaBDP9ehT30zkYB7/PjmtVQTycurWmO7Wrdj15J/u@gWiJi6hsQFprpHd0DE57OJWQyvVDrFK5U8NVAeoqHmEDwy7jtnU10hwiHiwYMHUIADSGomCLWMIUIGjviczlQvVo7f6eQR6@PzPqTKP8xRJORpcPsTNq2pzmChLLene72@1ZKgU26jOnKu6i5QrxUqyVO9Yd/yE0lJKKwG8QCVRYv7oMalsUq7aRJJbOYEK81u0r8bwEtK0AgAXvx45PXYsTOMzFY9MgPTM5Aw2KMR335hsk9HAwjXoc8zk@asQeZQIDIgKh5mlY@UoWUJ9bvjFKo4hvRqqIRXFFwdtPOJcVLtmeO21QUGnkimoaV/pIGoFGpmwUKTSl47DjyOY/hjPAEbRekHaWEeT4HrNV217LY5TqBawVIDZE50j1@8OI8DS52nAVIFvRcoj53TCR00RN0XLWKqT3musW1thY1sVln51haqZhzgRu0KgxRPfPcxGKF/SnQG@pAlRqT63mMqI2uinrDTnu8mmVLl2qNslkrRSBk@5AGSMAbtkIkIhyVwZjGRqUDtoKtnt/HzxhqymqaqDTBTIkm2irNke9CV4/xSUoKRD0QpEdgK1i0rYY449aqc8iAO@kukPZWh/vcF3qS0nJZjHMQFlZpV70eU7c2JJPLWVknUxiyr2WJAFte5vJoBsAtYSCB5An6FGhHAGl5RhFrTcZUX2MKDz0zbNgFBQDMDHfpgfQRE5ibTwaVv6emVNpRCjGfxE6GXBDI6e9XNfvyS1KKvZso04VK@gj71ZR071Y7oVieZ/zajZsqXidV@ZZIBQSdZTaz2KlpqfS2VWrXXEqs2dvX37@M8zdUqSBJNFYY9YwikrPaTZaBnkDwqq3Z5Vd9OrLYruTWKAVYYeF1ChHdeRr1c1a8yq/ehp06Di8sbb2LVI3XYWVXVriB/2EJWM2mgmUvUHky3v2Hyq1YqhXlQV5uYgXeZ@kmKeHb9JENTQmUhYWa6A9Hc5rhqWBPzd@CJOhbOoqKBseeQsYvjXc0gMCofCzYALPBbInvwhD/DtSRGS9CmFxXp5VmfuzMWwe/ipKmUKx/n@sgBgeMEIBGtaT2ZBGbys5/hpXxyYnWnsN7sn6fi@WwZXlo5z/Lso9W6oqzWcvls5cFqQ9f9usz0zMbao3Oz12kddjN1WWbrbCOTWcsVXp8NtcLalzX19bgh14qV9Fnj@IwdH3/xrvkuKY/PJ3I9wTZR5eBbWduQWay0ybYY/hY@myy35FmmWFGOA1AWi9XreI@evClnMrV4A/7J9yU8PFytqlbVnca7d8naJpRpPKnHtOIGY0cPZuElcrnkiWVZGVYfeu02/Jwea/A7GGP8SaUSChMOSo27scG4Q27jXbPbHe3rE@5uxUb4OfBF3CffePHiBRpe0MPePBPxOXQWpFFq6vkYy2Vzf/6Tlav05XFz@8@/NciYK/g5ws93r56g@UTLf7Sy8tHDhxsbacASNx9/4/jru7u7G4/S@eNafmdDya5s/9mfrqzkctu5zErD87RGvHZ29oWcy27I6p//ON48Pv6a52G14LPONDDiuwg/jeXz7Iy9geesw/CfzG/aEbOO5lbnDcvF3sQ0TYtN6K@Jqwc4XK4Q@4k@K0yr7mz@1@8fvY75sWou88KFrx97HSsUY9wIBrCtB7bzWDW2jcEKV7FJplKpgHHzv/47iF/9FOCgz2QbXtV8AKswiVWVCkV5G6sWwKDlcpDu//3Nb16jogc1eOSNzZy804BnjZ5toCiro2QzmbnQWvG@dp8x2@/5poMfi39s@DC9bMM49VktlUo1VAUetUmRMpqWq9PESJSWaKIkFjqXGXdhEbcpYQgX8HsRIyICKiJC4mbhQLTFHV7Mh3ux4Cm/@Md5nkmxwsoD81G1CqJMrppbq6boWamXSoTzZoZtFmXHeYCzffG6HGcv2WOB4qqcLebkdDr9oIn3mLIxYlIZx6ZoYxwzLDaDzxib2ljUKcaCaGwa5kPD7ePzF//7X/zgL75Pfz@g338EOjHtttXJrNUSa8nGebPKH1atylVXvqyT5QHLloqlYoZ8gR81njEt@/HbeH49foI7CIInmI@MhU@1iq8gG2irxrhLlZumbsKnGlooxDTK4nBMMKAAqTEpFmxIVGrnDVYNCrToqT2AapJzm1tyo5rL546g6jSZKm6L9VY95sSCEu3AswJ/9A/PDs60Cxd8r5Aj96GgC56VMDO3P/M5lWK1WC1jNrBvCAM9WCmtFEuFUi7TZMsBlZdBj51H2Yi6qRbVHDAOhdVWnnF6b7BU8NRTtz7PVbUpjGRw8Kcozjgmxf4RnqrEYpfwNN6t1d6tNYOka6KtpraVRjUlcgQftfmgkVKurmrql6lyWfyDHFkObfikygyNUJLGlaJsfwnAarNg4xtOvOA8QOgcOL3V5pfbAD61XduuOHv0U6m1KI0vq7XtWRAicw8epJDLPgAA1dUGS4KQqigrtaVlAICNBIOBDlTg1fZV9aq2fXW1vQ3/2/S@El9wvdq@9k@f6bMkzNS/gYRWr2Wq9UxdkE0D7Gqmii5qpg6GKnwhHHRAUuwd9CrsCX/YE9uGf/gJB/ja@KDJJk9uJ8OTIJBw5i5SbI0xs6St5dYz@fFHhX2Qo2oNBYd1FaWmFfINkmSk2Fvs@KHBbkmxDA6DtvhoaItctkDgy6yxtdiQaZvrsTXgDh5b4f5SDMoJAC6pfb18/9X/ir/6@6/@gLVe49/jN/j32se/UwP/nr3GP3b6Bv@e@fj3pIV/xx7@nb7Gv90W/p0O8O/ha/x74uPf8y7@SbEKiGqrO6s72X72PKudaWdgsFgWRg@9bE9rIx/Nmiw7yU5YduBobTCZ8JcFk5XtsGyXZe2srWngCQafZX00deDThb8OQHHhz8pmEXj2nEEqfeTOdDUEfd82WbIu1Vj8pQlSpqqpWbVgNRuo7AvEz3IsU69nuCDOchtl1BN2ddVs7j991GxmaHmi/sQ5mv4fHQ2i1hv/B0fOkyNn4MD/0dHRkzpIKNXUg5TyAJ5KNbUtPjuxanmnXlKQ9oNmFsts79Sr6wqaCyloOTl0S33gM4UI3@pKXYqzC@jyL8okTpQvzssXZTKE1hflJpiDACIYN4BjWYgh4ALx6i8yJEFcwHNOcMmGxgvwDEzckHlxUUdJGsZO4T/gI2r9B/i3/r/1/@Q5S9QaSWgDl1fbCXqS@JdMXl5dXol3NZlICEtiG/7QAewY5fKqikYKdAmmWiLZSF5dcTd4J5LbHGAV09iuUuRpQGjssTBNSpe/Ev@wX0xbPPV4GUTrympCrHPW6@NsNllugUu4MKK/pSWzZJk2E622alrjz36MEyzaTpIC5TfKZW2NcUtuI1cubwS2zWK5XAwsq4nE1vWnmt3RCiAnbGwkk@UyWHYCsFmwhmCLADaw5AGq6ekGtf5yLImF4BwhkcUpW7ocLC6X5Pv3E@Jywp3hMHn/vraVffs2dGo225bbbKL7@tu3clPG/UiVrTzYs8W3b4EZxZOOm3jq8JXwhKKxj3JVSmHLcaGkm@DNtExummZP93TfdxNvrGFaxu3znpykOxayWcetx3/6vW99qx6v4A4Vct3QEACmwvLb24WNarWwAeZCEVAhr/ItT4luaktLXq1mZF5cJq/GY8JLK24mOQuMoz@LbbOdKrRgDx92eRWjemUb@WSiNTGTl@ASuGlbW9yRbRQSxdSW@KusJFkV@iT@h8O39dTG2ubaAxy/jZc8yHbLl2ZFu6pcmiWc3rsqG@LyKDzCat6/v74FCC1my3Wp2Xy0e7rbxGvJcUMCCPkMHYmBS7jYPHTjNZqLzW81ali4Rj0eL5UfUNVrxTyLxcsinBKHnoAVtwgHktXBk@xQcIS5/Hf8eHdv/zSd24Y@Onewu5fOnTx/GNPQmp/ayXsd7c/2dx8dPYcIx4/3d0/2Pz78fP/5Mbh77GL6BNxUvKffqGmB/YK9kF65b3TT1M2RaTYvRqOL1@yVZTUtQGN/ZFmW03WZZzZN0xxCsOApw8@wPP3VK90d0sPe/@g773/0373/ne@9/53vvP@dH/z0qx98B36/B7/v8e/3/u1WHt8//eqf/@773/4dcPyP8Ptj@P3kp1/9xjf5j@x/Ar//HHH7E/GLhOM/CWD9yk@/@v6Pf/rVr/4Qfv9K/H54/fdrP1n8@8G3l/8w3vd/9@Yw3/t38Pt9DisI@73f5m74vRb@t3m4X/3h@1//9/z/z8QfGn/n/a//Cb6E5Z/98M/@8/tv/Ydcrvhn/@b9d773/tvff//tb73/9nfff/uf5t7/xr/RstHX777/wR/@9R/9/l//0f9E/79H79@/y//7H/6zv/zf/vL/@Ms/Er@fwO/fg@knf/kfgGb/7g9/hP/f/8O/@@Mf4f//8q//7g//5d/9yv9Mht/khv/nX/1b/v6bX/tPf/tb3/3rn3zzb//lT/72N//wr//PX/2/fuM//c1//wd/8z9@Cx1/8yd//ce/8lff@s5ffftf/NW3vlry/s6N76/u4P7VP4LL3fN5Fzh3KdeHunz1c@XnF8HGNBWgEyDwX37/G78ENP7r3PY/gA3@Q6/vhpYZH2757tQCEH5rQaRf/ulX/@LHoe2XwoAxszTbaRRzxdQaiM5rW1s08Rf4bV@HAsl9FxvlTArfxeb8/kfffP/jf/r@R7/5/ke/goxb2dhK76YV7ZYrgSBg/g7hMGDhLuEwICT/xRfwGqdowkxJoY19IQJ88cUX0vhtBsYv2QdvwfULcuIP417gx4RX4CfccXtvNAw3ZgPjKjq/jSYNZk1M9q5IOfriS9JS@E2tgAnyuybl18FGWUeftaA0KSmvBR4xAYt7jmlSfwz/0sYWi0Gk8Tg1hhEPGFJjlgKvhylWqVQocmVMQcGKccasWoTgY5yUqSB0iMTjpJtFBDF@SFAgZiX1jDXXKmMeMYXwqgSBModOz2QtJ6eKlUeQYGX8iCEsBE5gX76sVIuVcRXBvaMsQEKph5QnBFZJjavvwF4hmBBPij16B1kpVlKpahETxEJyXKWblKaWp8JR2VOMyo3ujNFE2gPGPpK1oixm2BFhPDS@U9PQO7TksQP@9dSaKA79B0b6rRHCVygpkQqvFkxshccXAQCuouBOR/gpCubmAXiPOagUJQufVEpUK8DDJwAJDgzH8ykpRfWbIgukH6usffCTqrIPePjMZbEgN1PaJAdSqVzYxKnLf3Lt@W/@yaJnsSs@Esfp6uqqFKvK6/IRrQKkYGDqnpU8X3dx6Zhk4xKTC1syOuM@twDH5uoxDa7XHq3BW4P//RXajJ5iZULOahwnceKMl5p9lOK/Bw/W2EdQB/SduklMSa07GzgVi@jeTqXkHKRadVLSl8DtJGhEBOitpI4rtPaQktJpxtRKDP3Y0dGRyBo5fFmRUtAGc@sa2nHaeDQaxSCGqqZVwCn/qvQlB1UYVPIVX3UVa57uT2S53EYZhPwy7jCWWFQm12Boho7v3r0DkqEdCaVDGEExsTkht1EkT3Dg54D7eMAlmHfZkviIkWmFDb6@R1eyJllSYgmk8qTEt0/ybISrgPFcsRhHUxJqRU2sBdtICpoUM0wUYpn0xOs@dMYwlEvLclor4JJmkqbGmHRayiHzkvZLWXh/3SmVKu@0jU0JvmQf4ZWy4gwvNKCe6Zrq9jYdepGqlwpNHqIRSl@QqlWx64NpUvVk/xQinB4xLZdVGQwELzc2cxv5jXxuvVDIb@a0jcLWRiFfXAeGXcjmczlta2Njq7i1ecXYS5WVFH5fpVYsJFVctWg6nSZdzMReStUv2FiFUpSVK6nar/DNwau4mUOuZ@UyzRoSGlZr2TT@5dbX4Q1JprX8ZmNlpX@pYAnqhNJL3C4DqUqXCtAsuwcPk@5J7B44wQNp4HI2ExuQDo/KYrMJnnBJ8B0nspaHppGU6pBRDk4aRp/yjG0IlHh5eRn5SbGVb3zDZ9UqDNqUwwMpBmynx4K9F4rVVnsqXW3fHrkm@XYZa1ufW3jPj9q2vGFfnwCZZ1UpdnV11QFIhwe4lkVWHqON7yuDXFpgvhrr0v///IM921z1VBUvRXb0dqUzsrnCG2ikyct2pe0YdOis3KnUGioe7S@31ZbTnqiePwGyFpVYibf6jnEWDzwtvJwOz@JWMnpGbTaBCnwHxvqVeCYT38lt5ksrGTej0oZ8luhAy97JFTbBsW5z10QHXPLo8uWs01aprQaZegIkC/FypVwhf7UttFNWoUyYtSpm5FLkr2Q7tnmF@7BLege42KXB9zqV5Fy@KJdr5al9syCXG1cPBmbb0lk9i8f@LhdGLBTkqyAcJI3nJnAyhyUGeP0UbvAvZevZ5JLIWYgMWaacSttC5VWVdq/UgKc08C7oWmM7UIZVlZiUyym5dWVdU7R1/L/FkMP/u4fPwX8O3xBrPSedoqKzp1DdwDtt9hgPgfgOO3X4YYOHprEkxF5Pp6u091zH836BMA91@4x7PbK4FqbQ6xMd723wBpbfWxLi@XCA53pN9x8Nwv6gBRlEGuQBHsLL7TvOogCb7PnxklI@CTUk4qY0UpEIwZ8dfvzJaeR7ur@794lUYA@Pnj6a@@RFoDx7vH9wGlo3uW8QNR@C@Pr@48fzVvEBMaNM824rLL8ZGDQJdzLeh2HAfWHMF6bGLBpf4AEdOpwb7Lkj@csrSafY7@LxS2ofVgsveqej1mNpzJVtCLFA29ySpCGd0tzMsjYedHGZ0@msgGNP91gL25Zn9vtINZj0heP229DEzBXpCW6V39L4WU7Lk@hANV6vi/e2@xJqcWo7FzYdU231RyYbDdlSR/igExpdvLCZ@RdOEEBq6TqD34c@EN@MPv7NDj5Pg9yu@fSvB5diku7rsWIZCNa/Krft0ZZ2/7527AKBV4vZUqmevQIKqzw8Kw3xtIFnDr398dYGEBwbsefQBHTXkOVcCdllKoODS7b6N7/1e@aa7cpyGQQ7JssFkva0tQNWjm2kWVNtxnS2hrXyrprpWtA10ERt9xkrQjxWzElIyWsZYFoxTZalmNVhWUklKLmtYr64tZ4rpotbxY28Vsjn01ouDXLo5hYIO1mtqBWK@S0tXdzYWt8A4Qp881ubUozvAcmsEUj4lgCsbeBNddt45Z@j9qpSjM/pszcJPcliemgfMdmEODJengxdDh5BWrMqcm4DzweCmA0QdWaw2MHBXvbgQJYfogWXIveystxGS76YzW4@lGWTfPZAAMzJssPjFFFzhuxzSzb7cE@WRxwA6p@U5R5a9gs4mpdlCy17uwcHmE4HLTmMD8HOuA@39APLJgSz0bK@TtMBsvw6BAfhdnlCG5TTfbRgmuhzwH32wE@WPw7yk80ChGc8HIfwSVDW3V1ZPuSW3V302aOC53lWP0PLLj2y7IIFWoksd8HQxb5PlltgxLYiywaYjIkObngvIOoptH1dliccQYgiWR5TaN04k@Vm4I7JfPLJJ3rPb5td/kxc/gUSPQQfazzaP2h9/HGr2225k939j5@hz97eJ3pnMnJb3ZaI1mrC40Ac8DkbTOYfyONhs6n3F/p8Bj72nE9z0jQxb039NeRJPF1MZNDcA5898Fm0IsKhwTOAoC18Hg7g@1BvkU/wkA99x62WXEZCReUiuIyBbeYMOKOdHuiG65TRPq6sMBZPxNOTWiHbKJMHG4C8li1foX8ngW8dh4UgWV1OauNKtlEZVzZz4hxjQq6Pc3lLTq8MdrQtEMb0HS23kRqX8JYSpxNncUXbSWj3194knoLQtb5Rkus7O4pc0xo7Oa1YKmx@uTaS5WQJ3zvrm6U3MEyLw1gMX8naZmMHJLxplM3NlJ7JlTY3k@UrQIcPfWlr5JvNZiJxYepnySRmF4cnUAQqK5tQOa1yJzFOjys8V2ySLI8rWpkrzWLZa7DaqK9xhLc0c4hdADfeyZaQNyVkbasoQ/qZTCKZBM5ETAS@090kL752enZ6@gXwLBgZimHTMb8KsyysH3@yp8JISthQz6J6gAKz46p7yFhmfLgOwMDpFJiv@omJ27qNwG2P63BQ98cw5kWpO/AI9GWpQsuRevrJDJwTGDPylPEgXJmUmKCaCFRDabWZXqmCSW@zBOWK6ckL6oqb1WqlWRmYg6E/gSIGsT5jpKNxCubQ43kPj@dR9Es8hio8mpXs1TT809GAPeSB6KxqEK1ZeQh9e7Zso75mE62rbBwbS9U2aqh8WHl4OSrhZMNV2ayYruu4cgwP@O7YlZHt6R3z2HTxbOnh0SrrMBNPcRq9l/V9DLmHYvmVUnWZPZOPhK5UW8lZp4gVEZf4GggkHCOXdJIClyCvYICT@DJZfg02d5Ul2urD5M5GGVD4kDVZEtyyLzsvOyzHChtluuOIJRAYtDJCHiJFT1aqnwFsDvqsVIK8CCI4A7CY1ioMD6w2@ejJoXVV7lZqGPotvrYVWW4oSu1tQ6qWpSo02vIkple8UYvfQp5tablsoTwGN21zo9xjrUrry3HZrQxheM3Kfah3MafAT4joeFoA8ARw3rxlife/9M3ktpKvcMcyAXvbB3kCuvPKeFpJ65VabqOQzhU2cAqisA4/LZ1bz@EG6HQuu5XOadBPQ/8N8eG3CfYN@EEY6MZzGk5UJPoJmTE5nR1nVS2tmVoayp19abVfJtNnCRBKCGfJtO/s20A74IAkBGRLVvjqyVRurZ9oO0zfVoiIgY@UqZx6useGFrwQzjNT7/PwSYWtryX6qwkMtHo6Gu7XGqXS/nj4NfBKKK93CqnNbOpNMllOAPNMVjzzNWEZ2Q5hYbgCRC3mX5g3GtSyK1DuS6WpXEF1@6vaZq5UG63WFA0KmH3b3ZarcgOq64oJKQe5CRd0pqLK1G2IwnXfhGrUtnJlSaWVah5QGgoOh0hjibocnGJKxOObuXg8GS/j3OWKzJJlwSWJpcWBv8bvazsyCE1ySd7KYYApd7yWmdiVhMNhtrElxS6lq8ur7ehs7mdsMtFTSmC9z1g3tSqxDO1FAoGPrZBJUas0v71b2e0@2y2L0Lt7UqzEWGQnt8TqXBmEkllh7EM3QKW2q1/ybx23GUKqEmk6q7EG7VowLRxIsc/xNN4Oi0OxdHdQy@XWG7XcJnSJwGaDoLmcVl5NZVgM9zGqVagP71LieKe9dZntVDVTl2SZmI/YQJIo5kF@5NvWc@G2dRZZv4oZJhT4XYzzgr3LYOKkhJdvJPQSb/i1RvLdU6t/WVxX@NgemNHVFdVJsAP4s5e5PNSS7QQOMMDxgclDj5XP4@xcLPNy6H0jV1x/cnhkP3IPzGBefaMpV2Msqym4ubYsHPNNuRxjZ0pcK9Em4eHJ1pebXxa/fPL86PnRgRSrr7xdcXDylAV1x97Zn34Nyh1f34gzVq/ExpUNccJFq1YVbTvHdoCNMyjuod3RCkr2bZXTa5V8Cjnwev9LP9wYbxfBngMZtQRYz6dy1aq2lkvGhu@/@gM84ny5//nuYxZHJTJ//6c/zm3@/Z/@a9qwEb8qezQPuBmDkGjUCpuxy8vh5eUVPNwvH2vEeKY2NpNg5ruBtNiUhEsZXV/bTG3kHtjljAirbWrJmKfExCT1Zj7mvRVeuWwRvPaOuE0u5OVkbP@Zlc9pD7ax2rVF1W56WzEpVnzy8i1jYDGq7W7XypEpk2Gldwrbfqdss3c4xfxOWWEvK1VcNtTwjEMwTbpWrVYRCotXU5m1OMvlwa92VW6kGE2zwqjuSxhFrdVnF1PqK2xrywZ301vzhNOaB4OwNZv@zDXPA2tgM9deeUxOsLVkJtNu06LVtsnyVaj5tQxkp558/0u/kcsV/v5Pf@1t823zC2DuW1tbBS0X@xn43nAWNxhS0XQynqpFQzgUY0sueFYNGAXird8dxsMHAzMciqF2Ca6bC23SuWMJBUxNQKwOcnCCgq3hicI0ScSkfiBZlqRQciSJ1@0aaYLB1lCnPbQ@6VK6h17QMbIKcEXp3hQUOAxQqZfR9Pojd0jz9AmKpzXS7D5EgRTuoRqYFToJKViropVxu@61qDzLXCMUSTNsYHoe6oGDTkC6B1EeA7XTDXtsqONpWgxp2cDLVQxC@SSPdg3SbkDafR6hSa4JKj0PkGY8dzySDVKxdA@PBpLUDP09s7YhQBm4xz1AAJQhIQBbDbbN1pPs0kqlylPFcVe4pxO1hujBWT0JoyG0Nh5QDSKXMZzFlcOMXFSYxkQNG2bUMQDCYfAFuQrI8xidbCgv0XHcO4MCWKSWIUFFY/fvT3NVqVjtJKMSIXzUmofK7qZavq4lAMCCkdBH7ZKcZnYqhZV9b5bsAOMpyi5QnUKGaSDsrWW0XkkS/N@ZaJEi56qKPMpYAFFfvFUYgDKIjGjndWig3j8tt5lkYeYNyLtBmSIFQuHwrj7@SCU9XgbP4pX0s1igJBpYz2l0vk7Q7fxhTQYd2wjV96ImCs4MxDFMfpEYsrBDP4gdxoKiWH0K3bFcGHzQgmCgiiixriUxWid0oXzQls3cBsPdlNDxwodiYWhUWKOj8heRzgpNspPWPG/o2KQthk7p405U0uHnSVw3Ds/2yL7QSe8bT4W2aEZyxJXpIeWTrjebK7TzeFxcRGy5MEINcJNmZlcltUi5LZbg6hlxUs0OwSUpEmW4BbIq4rjVNweQpRPTZKjdxCtlMl0QX0YtUmfyxAK66h1Y0I/YXkZcbZi5sM6szCmqq1WcDgjA4vhsDCUeK9QWJnSGkLK/vnVm8mnYxMz5Z4/lCmmQOdOA2ekPEFvCGV8845wF7zQPBb9N@GxyYzEdibuSmCSvf9e1lUQTa/Qt17vl4vWF57odwS89byUxfPUmXqDcgE7bgl0NWS60TH6eMY4HGsOjt5LQwlAhDQEqTsUPEyCtBWdy0SgNXfMcQiiahH0MME0jOCyMrRhKe486AGp70LJQo4/vlvAUfQV13SUMaHqCwdvsI7aek0jzIemVEGogAAZWfWUWOvhBVCyH57ehYlS@Agx8BVrnoA1@eMxRkB/GD6gbzaTdakrebEWAw06H0qow3iwCSz5iwdbBdRVC0VfAswA5XJCTlYScArApOSlz0GH8@eic2iXiJSV2HVKaIQSBaoCCosJD3ePaU4XqnouLC5U0Qo1cSzU9VEnu4bWsmWHXAvnWyfjmYCgujbLw6kBxLerUpPCLCPAC350x3Zu7dX/Cv5LUwfPsr0eWaybiHS@OfeA5atzuDkg1ByrN8IhuDixSzG8kaAXaE2SWa6QvAzIrIZkpxfgVAmEMwYzTk7SRBmDplnGW7ly0y8KD3zgPwKGyzMARlTW6gWXgBSZr2AlDOD7t/g7srf6Z4fQdFD1kPvs5TZqXMAg5CazCPrTGEMk2L9iu6@qTBPknMTTSaWJC0g2bQO9OPmCE3oRdcp1m1rg2acxEH4fRoe8KF31dVMwhXd4MlKuSQ/8x9x@D/5j7j6eJBsnWxg0ueaHTFRYHiRt1ZwUhEcwkCHPFNeFNfQgyCM9M4yAw5GTG7Qp@RoViB/jmNqjHSkAYQBOkgDKBmi9r9YbtmRdrjVSmCzQtEyKgxgF0rUE4vWiHZsR@/7w/dLwZJxvVUEHnI/KNTkZPUAOnFSxjWEFEGBxfFmor6g5UPlnD@31RYICA4hZ4ogSw6yesZDnU/EueQDg1eYpjnrGayEyDhCzhJdxAKuKo54iNAmpEAKF7WCTIJviwoOWIayYEE3jh4jXeQViFdOaTCuN4Iw6YnGsqnKWUqZIiuVKUIJuAdpRKK/NFCfyhKmpzXpFiXon6j2Z/5YOz34F2sTj3RLC8XyhL0aZijlFhqymaC2GVVSuReoUcZNb0vulCB7XPxVDRKUMya5lgNMHTwSJwRcOJSOUbSV4/dOBGtuVSSAqTSgWKOKnwZsnbRYBSjvAwmieiTQJCEPE5AwEY2YXRTBFtHI02rlQ442DjJdEuIpkcUybHPAoPPV6SyYaIBoOkUJUtVk8DNRiCQCUDPI33lqitV2aefo4qmdkr1E6EC40izSnPISoQNISSNNKZ0ViYei2S6QjTmgOAhHgNQJvfbFWS5hmepoS2kEdxVAY8itsEGXBeAQRGLLjMNdAlQiKjoS7I9XKK@gFou3KqJskabg@jvyz/yenAMfhp1x2zsyG1Wcdseu7vH8WxgZiNNNCIkKFlN5Ah44BllxTygFhy4bDEAuEZ3DPBheeZVt9pZQY67trIuJFr0JPBeIDUaD4YOr7uOxsbJT4Isoi@novgLHK3DB8DWF3bgaFGVGulxbVs2nFUJmo4XdvyzDRevM5FcJP2EHB18lJU7hVGx5MkMWvIh6UImhMQiq7NJl6112wmPLPfSZZClbBoVZEO43EJx7NgisQHPiSAHg0TTuuVafjJ22GiSlcR7dQyzhJHQ@EZh0R2GTArA@R58O2BqMI8ZzoSJL2MKBq3/ATp5u85A6cL4h3qUcXYc@APp7AxQ/pwSHlJMx2HqKWI4ltqDgkjrSdF1M8@OCr7LJfQk2H83CyAGWSkmTuPY8SsuyC55tLkeLQgvZMPz@9JNL8nN@eXRtXzeeZD7Qr3/LCk1xNTCBBwmo3127ORFmrLr2VnJiuhMwpQPMKds9imXVFtzOkuBN0VwdUO0Ec6tHmkeElk/PNl@L@5AoPo@3etPh1vHj2ZAL8Z4Ga9BF0n4QVLjQkIfphE3nM9uZC0H90xLQiL98UcoKwA8ioxLhu1ekHDHMIw2pPDZRcB@Baax81N1@iedjxVuOeCPLnnaXaWW15Fj5pts69PzHZChExH4AYlfgYjM@JXdys4Mjpieg4f1CWgk0pG1Xwj0nmg0hKS0dPnESXv18LwIFZIPTTzTTk8XI4/9L/GmnHKrsJnn0Hgj8djdB8AXd8wnAwnXBtqnxQlB3yU9z@8JvF48e0IATyIHebpabLJm9jns0RYpDv0CGFYdbbIpPcs6LacwfB6HX4Yim4vKVRuJFIlqOUZHezLaty6qcYjVBHQJF8DuhtJ3kZ0d6a5CKlxYFMWtvdhXcg1yLg7wjASUYjc5cYac@xrPAHdaN7NXtKrNBcw1DAmcTrfonE1yRdJCYfAh/DFCaTP4YsAu6bf5AQVlA3nqMT1PIx8BvowIrUIF5DGAUoEi8FNG5SNSCgpMEPwy6swTWNpmsa1NI2ZNMMWMJtkJJBkzCQpagGr56Yq6Jsdfwl3Ri8cJMPnJrYNj@3oLk5LXMateMlKs/h5vAQMOW7GS/sJYMrxdrz0iAxevHRChrN46TMwTNtW/G28FDQLDOCClQwP0F2wcLQb8dJeInkl@XgZSpCuGi@FdQphdriVMAKowHKD1IhLZrYjium7JnRsJFSmGVKMl8ZxEk24pOmXhX9@6wG/nQc8cc5yjQKzFNNmOo1Ij8HTgW4j0J27oCWXRG@@f3RAu4um10qAfwoGc9E4BB7E8Fh8lhnxjKEvrVDAFzKIfLO0OEdMm7175A7ZEakDhVIlz6ZP2FNJHmgnyL8GgRvJ2SstRPygvmZB8Aq8Wz4x8rJ8XstOkBzlCNdYkwuyhUh9Gb@hUFjXc/e18NqP1hDNXc8Gwtt7gyC8lghshKeDDEeLbZjY0BnOEgn54n51KxqHZt94o0TqnYtGXEG0zCXe5CxKhowh2viTNxUnEg@zNsOC0LOWbfBWFvYLxIvRa8rrIpIqb3yQhQjPgRZuGmcmku0jYaRwnN2kqa9Y1g0FcXmSxLlm2SREVlFPykj3eerh4HUftad82PA1iDnGSZUEAojEDFPh/NX5APnd4fJ7IFAHSJhLYJFgvbgrvS5e39jLzuW8P032egWiZ5o9Si4UjsIUpiiH0UFEMr@J1q6J@LiFgwv5PNEQ@py0H6AtHBPcgrf5sQWHhVKCez7reJYDx7PcckRdl0j652ogtKiYkoDDCx7mdFq0m/PKC76oitGHJrL1/gdXsDtbwdHKQ3hUAHcO5byVuyObdq1M2zYpJkYXZKlaiXFGTsufYTVPHYHd01JsuAwLDkfNZ4@Onj7@OnS6m5ubSdFHT6b5w1aLk6phP84h00bmsD9YMGzJpVExPy5e023TeBP2St2Wr/ESzqxBGMBLhgLyE208KXhZhJ/PtV2Ix8NGMCpgnU2bgT7DlVDU0bHLtgRefUCI6SfWdAEkEG8B32karSVxThaoA@8rbDap@2o2cTNSsyl6MayaYIU7@bPYSmbkuXTbMlcbfiFJdLybPTpiLz7ZPWWnn@yzg@d7n7GvHz1nL3afnuJJ5OPnDx8f7jH47T892WfTGQV88CoVHFACXh@Zhjlo4YXF2ewGI8h7znDC@U5iL8ndT/QB@8QxTFyP2vb0wYMet6i26Vd5rH0Yjk5wDtOiG3gGlu/zqwUNAEfCTZvOw@G@ewZhWzCmHeCYd@C0rY4FYSUc@w4t0wuOZbG@BTUI/DY4upnmQhJe60JbgeiaPrphEa/og/C4SANgdG96JaTl8QhmW2UCceHzwRg83X/25ITtPn3E9o6ePjo8PTx6esIOjp6B9fjrh08/Bnwenpw@O3z4HL0o4JOjR4cHh3u75MAzkFUZnjanOxdvyoKKwQkrxhkucdPl4qEtOusMwUCCZxc6nQz0WHxkI/ex9L71xmzHyxJe4sRPI9KaAAuvUGTma1zKDNZ8aT@B/Nyja4hWs2ybUoPGUoX2VhbNFbo9VB6PCw@DCcPrqMwynRtPkHl6zRVtymlbJpP3cM8Jzn3z4@XUlgPQkNAKwEZQwQaUCqObGOLx9DaBrEJqRt9BDXI8Nb4pUFgw6oNg60hZIoyJvS8IFM8NHNo4H6SVQwege3DIiWR9lwdg66EDD8A2uAOKooe4F4TlRYiRfzRC9swK3OHVYHhA679sM3R4qNMotijyxOuNqlRn4W0weNi@T3dp8FkeuvZK9wzLoigehce7KPr94O7JlgkkDzxR3BSGe9UgpAzMpoNLDWIbmz2ihg2@QA2470fv@B5LVJIqO8XNPqZt8UtKun3d5luapltxiPZYEVWiVMRuWSu8/YNOYgwdIkC8kWc2H2G8R0IqNO8aD2I@vJaiLvY80g1SwZay2zLw8FoGfh4wAEiZGekY1FPRAVAE43QEKSc8BygS523fRcMDObdHhjkTIbgZ9JX15k1SIDk9M04K9h1S7qCK8BLVNF@z7DgutHFiqwM814Jc0Og5Q9/idZiYLcH0XjcIjR0bpPayUp1Jje5ynUvRduxIoi2g4iWptoAo75IqUTxfJA/ZV9DWw4vlaB8dZkdv4eXa07WzNC4iXZg4/QKCML8UE3sbuuJYyJ/SlHe8o4tKi5Xqo4d15d3LNF6hwdkCvwou2ETILzYdYFrQPGidjzYguih3iZYW3MPijVoYW@ypE9wSW3kADMaBPQvGdQ@a5dCPbx@@7o7HVebdyfHt2wqPpSBn4hx55PUSU@6WZrUgyTTFaTCx1yPCOyGzwOsTgUuaYIb8@gEeTMFaKANGbOQjdCXx7P0ngoUEpWuNOsBZxA1norpD@ElWpa0TgSDJlbVE6yPzZeJhJVVNZqY7R1gEnYmARacDyHgB2nT/CfVX18A9uhkc8O@7gyvemDvePXwQtEc3QvugvCmp5bB4txSBdXew724Ayzu3nwsslD29HDDvJK9DCyk9JM70aizcHXtzii@v1R21PQCDfS/OoIRAI6mNbFqiDtS5JniEZBTMVCA6OX20/@wZk/n4BOIC38MhQ1uwQYS9wq@H4btnLZuYnRoKTeFgORSeApeZrWvBc1NjXoi8JaxCyCBpgY@QWcxesEpcT/QsJELQbnpiiAHmZnN3GfAgryYAX@H1pcC8YlMxLCygtLCYMd75WF50U7fAW5rLxtE9@bRjmvfdeK2aO4kCim7@0bt4UmRx/b3g8nEpSIcLWObrERW4DZI03hasshNIeAgBVXW2Bm@olqBKcdM8F7BjAe5wh1d2VsL@xQmKCIkL4VwWjrB1IRyLrHH5eDUQc2jnIXYDOm7pFJ58hzJ4BCyeXLajFZqcdnqJ2S4IhEy88OtBlCogeuOqHN77m5j2k5VQII@2tVXKTS3IZQNnZwXs8vJAH@He5sI8e5hPCrjtjUkp/zBJ8V5iJqUA5wsLE3gC5EI@v34b7PlSBNGVXxQ270Pm@ac/GML4fgrSm3g0vQ@Ue/g0HfhPCeAG1PGt8kGDmYsIos6CPmWm7NQZRfMHeeHzQpAZ1K1s9PB6s9lUk2w8l7fF0HmPFIVOQa6VIdKEw4LyVnMN@1c3J4cM@db0Vj48Pd7YMBDuEbz6WXi4LqLoJOKEB01n3UzXtSkYP5Y0cPD4GJ1GuvHMHB2a4xtaeWHQk5bZogXoiENGfFttOphioERoVlHF6xBxUq88P6unaOVoCQ8OH@@zNdJK15mZgpRdORlhOSuWfVMGiPXSdAT2GnQU7yOvBD/IQzoACWiiQ3kJwk3y1rwRRkBYrtGVFGLbp2Cp2nyldzxDt1HrRlqm28HvQ0SafN0/OkgumlDPlmfiQ@a8oZ2AWGlZUWWKCm44j4uQZkHw2kT3SD8l4Z0MYoPkDZcn6xmtmC1sSVQ6O@2nB7WtRnrNqMgM@lzdHngj96J91nV65x3WZ8NXrbExefOasfwGW4e0cve5VlGtUMGz3gm2Ce8i28oSwYoM7tCNXHWZMZW0gOJ6MpsOv8srLEkGGiuX8ATEHJWytUFAhXhSzq8MaoVGxa5ky4Oa3SjjWT0/VfFTWiqBDveh8wTWwhfka34Du9KfRWdbTfucuaPWhC6SEmc/GJ39wP4dZ7jEnm2aL6dtxtI93KyGZ0hU27xIhJe9I2VKKP9I9@gQj4ZHyWm6GGdb2hbkALCfBmHVG9N7kpTuZdXR0HfIRySkIAmxt9Zb6V5w6ihLEwYQpGY1guxsE5xpmASu@3DXCd8NrWhcGtPwqGMyAqKGMYnbyXVZxiOAmFFx9KrWkDzV1I0eZgKvAH1L0dj2Nl0ICiTlqTRJhzs1dJcOPmQbaMT1DfgMaTEBkyDB3KPjGxIUH@0aGrgLTUH5dN6FNrpLJAiiD27jZpd0HInibwMCOOLvcZFKFTOYQrACOZEf9aO5A1QCNjuux1UEPAXJK@UeFhZh8/QqU@C045twhMkKNIH7vQtEJ8cVPKIEika2a8UIwyd5cEIJLUMLm4e4pColryp@@tNoiUg0JYgWBI6g4t6t2MCJLBj9PDGh@UzYntnvQ6Y5Lu5N0YFGOo4r0k@F6Xs1TLMRZp77K9f8lRl/lfvzTE1DqdB/TwOVooHk2OU03BX7f9t7sq02kiWfXV@RSDaoQCs2eAHRLUDY6sHGF4HdHnALIZVA00JSqwRI12bOmXmYH5gPmI@7HzITWy5VKpZu973d95zpc9qUqnKJjIyMjIwtU7ZYdqavsiLZJA8z3cqDxGHLrt1VNsyPB42uLbxhppKp0nxYj3zIOV9@Sph9/jIXqWMI3Hw/4u9C38sy8wbKSNnvo/3jX08mKCDfWHEliVFpvt/tfcebk/mCZJYCbCrF1XG@iex4UUrIpLATENBQjU/LdqNsW1kqaY5Daya1sf59Ki/CxHeZOBgcdDizsBLWiIMl6nOJEDeh@ELohz7POU1Qm0hoSq/cDV15KpWnTrNYak53y0GLMwschhZf4mUMY/yK/@jFHgVOl0snf3zEkE948ByMHEUQMd25VDKaotwEwz74pQzqjl3E9j2Nt5jMJN45Sl7TZ8Ah0x3Ucs8ZPuEyCs0pZvBuvgimbYGSJt/bphA/3nj/W1j0XjdBhB72gomq4CmiSdFUXiQeHZO9hphFiXK8hJfDYQ@NiiTYXVPEs6TzWF5Ba4pt0TGj5b0aOu5w@Sw@Sfw4VMqrPWz5Gv0/7Ifw8gwvJke7DSZPAtaKCpXuOO9V@lPWV8CaebrMUeGBugzZKAqH@TMXCJ45Xj2I6XDYbAV5D2SxEKQcj4fa4fUt6nIMC8FEXrClvfK8v1x2Wz9vvUZz7fNS8WnJQdmVWHuL@afPbKAUIEl/WC6CuLpSeuZ5jum3xabfHDaYVbu40X8A2gyu8PprrwI7BhUMQTgNg9FV0M573n5gbLzYLpIyGh4xbHpwOWqx7gZkK7w2G6N9wyxbu4DC8C/uz2wNbpEpLOuhTcoak2Gqr7ptRKAOKOkM0PhL9giM6md8YKWLYAxIWfRVFCQyLQssJLtcoJ4JsIFpSRzTg0FDfzDutmBmSFHl9aAptnLYzvrtGCTQX6vXxCDffBIAGP1iMaAB0Jaiu2DwxCb@q2BQMjBtQm/qmSkA9xvQWoHlHoy6wH0tgmlWqJoDO0zwwZtaXdX3dg4@VvarCp7f7@99qG1Xt9XmJzJhox2cssmqN3u7wF2MsZyN4nvwIlWpQ80UffAq7z6p6o/v96v1utrbV7W373dr0Bo0v195d1Cr1rOq9m5r93CbjOvQgnq3d6B2a29rB1DsYC9Lvepqnq2n9nbU2@r@1hv4Wdms7dYOPlGPO7WDd9gZGu0r6n1l/6C2dbhb2VfvD/ff79WrCgfmbdfqW7uV2tvqdh76hz5V9UP13YGqv6ns7sYGuvfxXXVfkQ@AM8rNKkBZ2YSjKvZE49yu7Ve3DnBA9mkLkAcA7mZV/X11q4YP1R@rMJzK/qesNFqv/uUQCsFHtV15W3kNg/My92AF5mXrcL/6FoEGTNQPN@sHtYPDg6p6vbe3TbiuV/c/1Laq9TXl7e7VCWGH9WpW4QVb1DW0AdiC7/C8eVivEd5q7w5gzzh8j@4MPkzyR0AMQFmBqtuEYPRywNECkvb2P2GriAeagKz6@KYK7/cRp4StCmIBHSa2Dtxi0CEg8cAdpnpXfb1be119t1XFz3vYzMdaverDhNXqWKCG/hafgHSg00MaNc4TwMWPQKyeptwsTaeq7ajK9ocaQi6lgQLqNaEWQtvWG8F5HhPTOsqS7gB1A80LV4HSmX11FWCex1nNS7IuxiQ42trbrsKOLImlUvbDIew6L2KZj9xvsNOYj/AzkmGmHZxenjW6/c4AY0VNNVZwXIRnWbwqxMcbGI69O@7nED0KVUinG40PlQYcdOuNhp99SM0IGPfVEC33XaV8GSMmoseTNyp4Xr1ivK9HELUxL3ZM8sND@wKWZOzPs2db8yLwVaHQDqQaBuFjw1pFFLJV5BwtJcAaKZYR74ywXZIGgn53hRyoYkY3n281UA2Kjo9UaBDCP/2v9gdvDs4L4M6s1ioU8BBLYHT/GuhuuBNKbUD/SGaBboe6zIdB8PNZpuh2h2f@/Nlg0M74vq5DZcdwDjzL@PdUPw3OYtVz8foELFmVJXd9qM/dJMIY87KgTMm85Ec0sgz@0xjTH19Dw7kbUClKXZEuWpSTmXmujg5HWSUpKjB6giYZZb63lR9rH/E0V1x@thZ7/8a857WF7oCYDxY2vCOq95n@vPnMBWCBUU4NQElXMl0UCk4d7U5iCl9DwXMsRMn9aa8@D2hfB5SAIHvZ7Ll94m486k5c6IEPv96vvN083NkB1onQPnux8nx1zTNZsn7M8t9P2A8lVKUkYUPYx0FOo0/OKtkCwYdWipPW2pI/EXChgAUxs7meNHqJ@RqMW0bUUQkZGQ43xAtU@uiBlwoQDylFiTTmPE2viStTCCATGaqPo7loTkjEb4KsRDQgviq9Kc3aBP/Bts3y10vcDEgISEiM0tgC5cLpgvheakd7gtLhhvLsYJF8StMxZ10zOCBVF7nHYvAs/RLadmYxZE9FXK807VQTgJiLQ6G020SfV/Z7yhciil5K9gVvfhR6g8dPko@OstM1w3FlXAc07piaqI@2SmcZ9JG0/HmjDFM0P296WleozfcFKFp7ojY2CT6c1UCgfEafwbKKNbxm8oHEuyQH1@8XfPWFKRWTcGA7a0Kx8hsoN2k40sqazgMiv3V2CcVtmWQljLVr04eni3wy@Sg0OiNo@iZ8UPt/IE4S2l@HEye0brHl5Ox7ECapVcYVHF8JKd1rbVBwrBgWm@6rT7aZG3dizs3AxEoz4fAZQIHMzlS/@ERZCjuZBAQgkaNiw12/xuPsvAlHp@9TvlRHe0i/dTHMKNkr9FYx025u9XOWxK6stqHgD1/5rGtyOtyFqup7Prid0qqHI1PsKK@ehCluztd5PAqLpAAxC56o9JydUuOUVZRVpvmApExyNpy2yXwEYunNrda5ReVktIzwfrFwaURB0xsIz@w46cqNgWLv22iCRL6i6oCS1mHmbTwm4@YjGeZOyc@yF2A7T9qkDMFbOcbXuEH0uHXKrGdbU5kn5AeCnVinQpsWENmtnwfU0rZ6baAnzSRSqIH@sM854QPWaukSec7fIRC60fB59bY5BZB7Dxs2k1hhsT7IomsidsZqCamPN5C0BoMRiI5NHDfAmO1O/bz6KEqHoB9ejiTdIOxn3ZFoJLTQD92g2MSnd9pmOFU6gRZ2xxiM0M4TfdCQLgJ0AOXsI5PcqsoA8Woa3dBKx@5kqaQy6/bLOuCEsogSEtfVqvr6lUsxQiXDZ0AY7IbmcEEumdQP2h3M8rsejH7GvR9FoH47aJtEok6TpAvkSar1KSVja8xDHw5C0mjAVKAGxGCixIo044cKe/RzISdxW0rZZJaYapRG8uv7MUSqnaGgI0u40jsQ32oOJhOxtCyZPE1uz9LyCoGSdOC6ufUwRsk9o@ZplTruG5byioWI8hMtOuIT803z9AmfRMlffhLi6oE3aMsWERQBRpkV7aezfI7gw8R8H7vBqO3qREGSaTeHqH6jo8@gT7SoVYeSvq/VHIfBFE4ArUJ3UqA2GpkfBuf9xtag1zzrDrpNOKdhwvQJczx8nNIjTtjZaHAd0uU69KHtFGpP7TOnj@F0avjb2CXXnBRb4TgYZlx3hPFoWjnnLBCkOUcfP2X2K6LvYTzXmanzbMVW8qLhpeRuV/LXbq37tJRUmS332IAwuI2YpwSHiI4p7siJLV2bKXB6VwEHxlOVU03/Foe8CMQvAUVkholArIGZcT9wB4Ens1shPmpPsm3KJTjCPErBdoC3v4QZep1t4q2wwEW@Q4@AV6r0ouhUZSvKBPMJ4sP0dnQvP/@DoQcAvgH80tMkakkiBGJxHZ1MKeTziiQFBVjI@69LPJo4MXCx7hnsQr1Io41JvNXo5@lt2CAPHxCKJF3eDFXiiszAwQfva8s0gOU0pj5uKgtqwae0HCiCVMaZ4u0EG9znHkuLH424rDlDxrQlLWccoG9DVQuwhJdnxrxnXZA5BfL9K2Z5@aGzFkNgOcmjzLliNZPSkgsFmHR5f0Wz1mAEzDgVw564eiyE48Fw4YHYu5V3JGZYS8J1y/fv9fNlYivDZrnYJtSWp/g4XfPi8MSIJoox8igDGsLjKz0bMo8jcVJu4HorN6b34OE2nFn/KLOpmPlu89rHTfEKHXb1RmOWFMGOyUbXzPujBgy8cTsHkTb5eNUgjtFAltGY8qPTVAxNBksPxxBRn8Aew0cbMIf9tgF37vzcitS4M5xOXao/RZJVIj4xzzrGZAJfGnbQ@QKzwLGEa5iUETgn2SmZ8kq5U0wWjB@4QZSKg5zVQ7EG105WjI4omX8n00BvoRJyInjacD0cTI5@gzBKoi/KHfF4aExzpc9r3NLEtASnCip1V0s6nBx@HjUm1MoMKmCJJ6DCjGiGN50/fFTfOhYoBy1wbfosjrzFLA7GV0sADfzjfmpMUAa2XUnNyIqKLoQGsQZYC3BKOesFfFxF6a87YopH7wZZRnCA4NcZ/LMkNTD79mrRYBurTNpTLOILunm1@Sq3wVUsQfFvRL8sRRZ16eAKDQQMMdQvl6AFTE9K0KNRgDLruJQXAVTmCCqWS7gs4SVlN7X@nAnfEalS4NmKU6KYVOKl20YusREQLJLLWEBAZkkuYluBjS4RFqfE8@Tx2BIgEGvaZ4zDVMisRHFoZo4RCI8EreEoRyWVLQoF08dnK37ko6Fv@vqy6Hwtxr8CfgyER7lS/OuLYuRrpNvl5WjVSE3Ah@/2GvkIqPBdgA1X@Lb/KPLETV1ufEKdQ0ZEyhA/7D4epa7x3Jb/t1CtU8y1ljF0e27gtz5@NfhGlEhy9bsTqStJ07/27YPVjqkaEMnsT1nndChLhs@DJLCmcKfHUeFBV@fRM@kH9JF20FEfDnZ2IkldT6faz@giGK0Ui0Wk4VM3h712oUZNUndQiJYudC57vcLw@ofRh9MCsX68ZL4XDl7pA3QAMwJrIswPRmd8jwPCAEWxdE7CVPGof9npuBcmoIES5w5mjUtKrgNF@0/X@Lx8OCD9DzUp@@sJDhDHd6LM4rtuspwprWgrFNRGj@CrlDaeAXrwRQfdsI2hihpDvqydmWDb8ssbX3ADwXtIaLIoC7H/xXonp94Evd4gqz7i7byYB@DRTbzCzo5bochF0MBIsbuXIWWbzargqttzooaxiEvq2Jzel/StEDq9O6a43w/OqpNhJnX0Uwp2FRjyEg5zCdNMZ1XqLOVLzvcHNMt0CGA/qPRFc5hpEZ7ihWGnlwVsnwCip6Vs4tEnUsQnlZjg7P7SiNRkcPOUigGG7pMooFPS0/TSSG4pbpCbOp6UOojDIrchMGFGlYfVwECyP44rXo07nYcxRcrmzxP7D2eIZAKgFSjLD/CJybD/JQfLeieWLoTlG7xzY5bvYIUGVvC8J63yL9eZSqWiHg@XllSlsgkPuZyqbFbUNr7Y3FTb8HsTf8@Xl1dW1pjnbvtf4OWmfnmjNqENUnAutc5H2/ATvpUxKgydtXGKHxfKj7Nrjxvl9Y21sHBU2cSgfXj623/819/@878LFfnxP/hjk34c/WQK5fP5wuPWl8fzN2v4@2j788Lj06PHw88LZ2tIZcjuD0dhs9d0vEfzLe@eCKl2r3t6W9SU8Z7phuSqie6SGfinXIYT2Nev/HQ8to8j@4g5UW31Zm943qTqilrYKC9UFubn4Wm9vPCvC6Q7kfdN8/6v8F75yMspaQKhFu/9UZX6Vq3mph1Hrk/SeyfAHDl4FabkyxHD1UlaXyGYO1L5vPqcUycGPHTzaHDBKIh8zGRg/l2A1KMjnxyyXcuxAY3SpPpmdTwbpi7CM5LvtOqcLz9ryknlSfsV29CojSVgeFh@jX3VJe4Vhw/gotmrnDsqra58zqXTac9ciNZoEZuj3obUl7kgS5vQKT8Dh2ENYcnA2OmCujLiAhpEZKTTdF3WfIuvdcv08WhNJyY@cKcXHHke9U00EM@wOdZwczIFlLHwwEdXkKnwkqIwUDaYPtSGBwBQeN06MS7FlxSHw6DV7UyNywPeSGF7h70SQ@YWVWcmYk6lRqcpGddcxzYICEEpgHL1YKPxBhl5AyjbJW7HY9S/QdyYJaoTSf6tntEEG4eg4aA3PetBZxlypQqvgTsB5n2ZrF5fh9JhD1zzNACpJ5AVzRNmfXkR7tMAVRH9FlrI8H6oHubkYoGPzb@UjRLWA0o4cj9cB0NBMr0@OxANOvAIGz5G0bEJi8hwCbdUISg81OLhWN8vJ3xgcej7asglEavw2xrfiTxIBUnnYbnoTtKEsDVm6EtNfLsulDbEq/3wIC25QX1ZSSlaK8b6BlLlBdoq0U4JSMGSebpLDFjDVJ30@idm/GzdDPE6wnxKd8ndLLN/AnAs040Ol6fuOBYgxcpVunkMLZyM3uEgDLungCwYokwTpUDk4IERtHq84HFnQi1oDkQE46vFoVlR7vg0KQWTIcXnM7yPULXb11QQKYgGUrSJBWi7wxwHA2F58Ks/6OeI5Z4G426LHSi59znNi4doFyczJQF2e0dweGjiOM0EUw/HOruQmItpqm07hCcMVsD1f25E7ybhTNS8wqIlcAQAMsRhZufYIsm2aCiBGogiRWAk/2/B4KMIYfaCs@44UicrGRjY7ZxHcaNRj4v8BAF2sRvDLAZKaEuzYQkngm/tmoGMV38DRvvCl@DnJNrTg8FdjS@eNDV5SBRP92KWPgw/0uC4UMMKBvTh8s1GZ4g2V9zrKIkcpvJsR0lV2Vm4swdqXEBkfrFIAT7UgHCLOE5yR4CN5Rg2gJ3GloHlwsVI8w4BI3G7OznxqBh6ebpYJJhh3ppeNKRIBDeeCen58vfuNzKVpyOMT4bFB6WQDmCPtg4nJo9GvMnEFXgdaEFdkuMBaxxdYkY6dmSRHQVT2HR5kTqdGjhiXemhywznSFIaUn4U@Hm04M5lrKoer639OVo7t8AhXV90YFfGkXSGvsR7yddHvJmXVld0uxyxRaY3@nWjQ8skMss4TOjZEZTT9trsIHrQIYbuWDKTc5NEGvoMr7m8HrNIFiBcRhqntshEI@Vcn6AEJLGvQuVyPKiNf3@ZnnJLi63PvKTrVkEuaIIYLCJC0y/IEzyi97H/ex0LkA90gRGw/1ozDODZ81jykBNm6m14tjmYZIrZ49RxKltafemn6Jxs5LB0K4STUboVcLY0vLJRzp6UlZH02lcBs/DRabfdDvo6FytUld7Mp4Y0e4Tq/C@G3YV8w22KmHiQcnh5mINJpBeCa3oejppnF016fDc4GDWnNdiE6Oden@ezju3tw2aEdzLRl31eo5U2iBqpGzwnW5p40BDJK6oJkk9rTKIBZ@JzxIUEBAQzCOA@zfjD6GAdNLjjZ92FkZ5p34RJPWEJJWQn6hM2nJx4fOHvBd5I2@B3QJsZ50ZgeaRPsWuqRUbAD9pB2HnLNVjU76GlJ@hH7BA6dbAQHl8bzbWyqgcEWtRHrruHMmB/6BMDfXgiB5tx67xxcdkbd2VkM8PS48JK8buP6Tipr6u@5f5jUhnGceeMA9s96sIqtWcZYlQWC3II060450eNbho/qR2t0CBHFU77sfyM6KN4s3bH3LB0v6GPGpiVwzHY6MMpjtNzjhtQe82z@6wyo56LHD4QDkAKgrE4pIuniTXfuHOMM4x5Q4iZmMn9R5zZ/5kPufyGrA0WS/pcKu6ZzMPsWZ@iCrKqKEZs51QLlMI3jw8uAjnZynHCObw6t8ZxMs0//MB6z8ktIv05qNJe267sMhdZaBHhUPtrOug0QgztzO4s0FhdYcSVJIjlDCUxAuNZWrrhqPREtsGHEijJMMeFbC0xmZEmsDdoYmbzzBoxYuaTr6U3IwFRUaCptmaqsrvZjU38fVGrZ3cwDWtUpnRFdmU3UCuzJhzCDRnci6hgFlGl34YohisJT/zld0NTFAFRLN14XhL5GtYhrlnuWjcRRDN8iRA3ZwThWBsJgu5pD5MGWsDizcEEasn@pRaGF1XlDNhiVBZmx/CmfcenHj5AhrGQcaOI4zCEyxEm1U2DdOXB/5jgGLjUBSp0IhoQEFkLnilE8WGIDcK30UZIygJVSPue@AwV0nxNUOl5yadOHtATRuB@g3hv3qXQHENO/K2Ud/8mR1vaLdrnyDASNc/AeK3umbnw4nCIsQP3KaMLaclYkVHQvPLVb9RDk0pkmbcaVOcU0t4jAIEFCkydB51R7SXR44YBDMMk3mStrfW24mOg1mf/mdTcGsfaJYEn2coBRS0EoBhGNz3zBIsgQPGqtA4XnoQLgGoTIpPYi5XISCok1EYIVm/UJdmRE/U@ZlZoMw6VvSh1NHaUh4nKUa0IUunEaiqDmURRaUEWoqCF@m6jjAp9R@0r2oUCtC0XbwNYHA9pmoxwJXc48/NKYCPNdEyUSDzPRxDFcESQcdyXsIoY6QKvwZeEeNk5YJkY4W6YqGbgAlLCrs75ZHkDuagVN6wipmDxftk3mE/GDlW9Cz8U8zCIhRURTohxmhQvFhrv1yI0js97iJT0dv88VPqrZuKhpCrXc99Gi7zlPi/ZLXdz1Bw/aMe1Fhr23zYXycfhDfOeqv36Hfoh2/Tig7fp9CKpOBftbr2YHsIe9PQ3tvF32batWg4/GQBTOG@ktiVBEzAJ89BDv1KrwhUidg0tv10K@P/d7M/KJxb/9LvZokF/K7qnLdo9rZW4p9kCUquF6haqZ8oTF4DV2adz0aLsgtzfINofrBvd3yCxP75/W9lyUnlA3eLrhG7H1wOpYQhVOiStU2JHyFJ5TZ@kZG2fqMzsgub5tlz5qbUKWDZxD9uZhgXUBZPqHx@6LU7DQHH/NjeGWnRzYzxi5ktaZPiHx0bhZGOT4wWk9HDsc85o64MXjvPhuIGNr1nvEFSziUd0uw08CYRkijfNqtPLMbmIKofudfwD5X/hmTSMIZLMg6GA0Swq6tHoULl7oYLTyw6CElecSW2rNlOkN3O0kzppDGGqI1k2HkFz5P1JgfboWTBocdoWOFjg9w4lbSG1Y4m1Vqiv4opH@FNC3h91OItsR2iNR6AWG9KtjEHgoUHwzGNuu96L4oti43ezCd2y@0QsMUql5lRp47vnx5Pt4vHk5bO9X9Lj9MZy4eMI/o7Tv6RXX6T5ER7g11P96yq9kV7HYqs36WmhXC7Do7RS2YFWNn4wbWKp6Tr8s7Gi212dpjdyZar@Nb2xCg@l5WWA5HhSfXk8eVHE/1Nrf6YtytW7mg3qtlaHlO1CmAZbCcR5liT5QWib3HI4SA0JQEvwUdUJ7g7QaI4ARrP6ZPlFUfYzIB8OC78K5GYeHVAvMgZllhhTrgP2xdYB4eLFw5WA/k0XPvyhLmhHkO3ZhqLrKHTcSSzQ6uRJfhWNWicSnW4AMJHoJIqwkydImhnqGBMf4d@N4ncpE6n@KhUJj49aPYRzvhDO@X8)

This is the hardest my addition by far.

This answer is supposed to work with [gpc-2.1](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/binary/gpc-2.1-with-gcc.i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz). [List of binary downloads](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/binary/), [installation instructions](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Binary-Distributions.html).

The polyglot doesn't work with the latest available binary distro, gpc-20041218. It fails on `\"` in a line directive.

### Explanation

GNU Pascal supports `(*..*)` and `{..}` block comments, `//` line comments. Block comments don't nest. There is option `--nested-comments` that is supposed to change that, but it
doesn't work in gpc-2.1. GNU Pascal supports both C-style `#..` and Pascal-style `{$..}`/`(*$..*)` pp directives. If `#` is followed by a number it must be separated by a whitespace
to not look like Pascal character constant.

In all the languages in the polyglot that use C-like preprocessor GNU line directive can have garbage at the end only when it is complete (ends with `4`).
Moreover, clang and gpc do not accept garbage at the end of GNU line directive at all.
Both clang and gpc support `//` line comments. So we can do this for the first line:

```
#1".."3 4//..
```

Flag `4` can't be on its own for some reason, `3` must also be present. The flags are explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html).
Note that `//..` is garbage for languages that don't have `//`, like C89 or Fortran.

This works in all languages except Befunge-93. We must have both `3` and `4` and they must be in ascending order. First `/` places `3/4=0` on the stack, and second `/`
divides by zero, which displays [a message](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X9/h/38A) in stdout prompting user for the result.
Looks like a dead end, but as it turns out, line directives (both GNU and standard) support escapes in the strings. This is confusing to me because `#include`
directives do not support them.

Befunge-93 doesn't support escapes, like most 2D langs, which gives the opportunity to redirect it before it hits `//`:

```
#1"..\"v"3 4//..
```

GPC requires whitespace between `#` and a number. This means we have to switch to explicit printing for Pyth: `p16.q`. Spaces are needed before `""` and `3` so that Pyth doesn't implicitly
print those ([try online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23+6%22xxx%223+4%2F%2Fp16.q+5&debug=0)):

```
# 6 "..\"v" 3 4//p16.q..
```

Note that `6` is used by Wierd.
To change as less code as possible I tried to recreate the situation with 2D langs as it was before, so:

```
# 6 "..\"/Dve" 3 4//..
```

`/` sends Kleins/Haystack/Reng upwards, as before. Reticular is sent upwards with the first `/` in `//` because it supports escapes. PingPong is now sent down with `\`.
`D` sends down Minimal-2D and reflects Be/Trefunges-98, as before.
`v` sends down Befunges<98/Shove/Ahead. `e` sends down CSL.
All other stuff in this area is to fix other languages.

A space after `#` together with `//` trigger [a bug](https://tio.run/##Dcm7DYAwDAXAniksaM3HiZ08jwMSBRLQhCJMH7j21lL2azvfcS2tDZSor7X2FEnnuZuO@6EQHAaPAQyHmiQzlsCSkX1hWQSSYC4M9aiq/q95bu0D) in as.
This is the workaround:

```
# 6 "xxx" 3 4//*..*/
```

To simplify requirements for the second line I don't close the `/*` on line 1. This means second line is not visible for languages that don't support `//`, so
we can use simpler line directive on line 2: `# 1"7"//`. This allows to keep Japt working (it wouldn't be possible if additional flags were required).

There is a bug in gcc: flag `3` enables `//` comment in C89 mode, [try it](https://tio.run/##vc2xDsIgEIDhnae4wKJNCGlddOjayejofBxXJCloeiy@vNj4BE7O/5f8ZCNRa6bXiKgPSpk0wwDjCINzXecGZZ4rxoyQWQQj7/Q5FQZ65MylQhK4XvReGV6Ef7DT9MUlpHl79dp7r/85be1N84JRmpUaRjqemr3JSypne2cMvG6FPg).
This code:

```
# 6 "xxx" 3 4//*
# 1"7"//...
# if 0//...
```

fails in gcc C89, [try it](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19ZwUxBqaKiQknBWMFEX1@LS1nBUMlcSV9fT08PyM5MUzCAsVPzUjLT/v//l5yWk5he/F@3uCTFNtnC8r9uMgA).
My hypothesis is this: `3` on the first line switches `//` on, so gcc sees the second line. Line directive on line 2 switches `//` back off, and
then it fails on `# if 0//` because it doesn't recognize `//` as comment anymore.
What I don't understand is why it doesn't fail on the second line. If this hypothesis was true it would fail on line 2 with `invalid flag "/" in line directive`.
But anyway, this can be fixed by hiding second line from C89 using line continuation (`\` is doubled for Retina):

```
# 6 "xxx" 3 4//*..\\
```

However, for pre-288 code to work properly, we still need to switch C89 to normal commenting state. This is done right after the big `/**/` comment is closed on line 548: `#1""`.

The start of the second line `# 1"7"//` performs the same function as before – it contains Japt code and has `/` at column 7 for COBOL. Space before `1` is for Labyrinth.

We opened `/*` comment on line 1 in languages that don't support `//`. `#endif` on line 5 is used to open `/*` comment in languages that support `//`, including GNU Pascal:

```
# 6 "..." 3 4//*...\\
# 1"7"//...
# if-0//...
#6!@  >>if 2>2*>...
# endif/*(*...
```

Spaces before `if/endif` are for Ursala and, to a lesser degree, for zkl.
COBOL's `>>IF` → `>>if` for shortC.
`if 0` → `if-0` for Moorhenses (esp. Moorhens-1, where `if` is Reverse).

Space is a wall for Labyrinth. `#` pushes the size of the stack to the stack. After executing it 4 times we have `[0 1 2 3]` on the stack.
So to print `36` we just need `6!@`.

For some reason, SQLite is the only language that doesn't have its `/*` comment open after the first 5 lines, so we still need `#9"" /*` on line 15 for SQLite.

Main Pascal code:

```pascal
 (   *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
```

`*)` needs to be on a separate line because it belongs to `#endif`.
I inserted spaces betwen `*` and `)` in shells code.
Second `(**)` comment is closed on the last line: `"( *)//dd"`. `""` hides `()` from Befunges-98, `dd` fixes Pyth.

### Other stuff

**Line 1**: `_` in `_lv` is just a filler. I now skip `@` in PingPong with `0=@`, which is simpler than using `#` and more robust for Hexagony. `25` is just a filler.
The stuff that I added to the filename: `\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"`. First `/` needs to be 2 bytes away from `"` for Wumpus. `a` breaks two spaces for Trigger.
`*` fixes Paintfuck, `4` fixes `*` in Pip. `h` fixes x86. `f` is for evil. `b` and `g` are for Alpabetti spaghetti (`b` is redundant). `I` compensates `e` in alphuck,
it is uppercased for 05AB1E. `/` fixes `//` for Trigger. Second `\"` starts ["escaped string literal"](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/blob/master/Documentation/Syntax.md#tokens)
to hide first several lines from Pip. It ends on line 4, where we switch to the usual `` ` `` for the rest of the polyglot: `` '"' ` ``. `''` are for SWI Prolog.
Space after second `'` is important - it is "single-character string literal" in Pip. Pyth and Japt support `\"` escape sequence, Pip and 05AB1E don't. So `a/4*DvehfbIg/` is
executed by Pip and 05AB1E.

Inside C comment: `26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"`. `26q` is 05AB1E, `p16.q` is Pyth. `k` in `qkp` and `x` in `.qx` are for Beatnik.
`k` in `,k` and space after `Pk` are also for Beatnik. `k Pk` pushes something to the stack so that `PPX` wouldn't fail with stack underflow. `PPX` jumps forward `xvy=16` tokens in Beatnik.
Also, `PPX` is a jump forward in Trigger. `*` fixes Paintfuck so that `[]` won't loop forever. I hide the rest of line 1 for Pyth in a string that starts at `"` in `]"[`. This is
also useful for Japt: even though we are in a comment, the code is transpiled anyway and it may affect later code on line 2. The `"'"` at the end of the first line closes the
string in Pyth and Japt and then reopens it only for Pyth. So the double quoted string that hides the most of the polyglot in Pyth starts on line 1 now (was ```` ```"` ```` on line 2 before).
The `""` strings on line 1 are hidden from Turtled between `#`s. `:` is for Chip.

**Beyond line 1**: Japt requires two killers `[']` now for some reason. At some point I had to <s>hire</s> use 10 killers, which is scary. Some thing can turn Japt into a boss.
Three backticks make Japt enter infinite loop in transpilation phase, so there are still four backticks on line 2.

`[]` in `[+++]` and `[(*)]` are for Retina. Space in `@ 0:8:8` is for Cubically. xEec code is `h$s o#` now.
`[` on line 8 skips `!` in MarioLANG.

Added `.exit` statement to SQLite to exit cleanly.

### Grass

Main Grass code ends on INTERCAL line now. I like this solution more because it simplifies thinking of Grass code and because
it is easier to add `w`s at the end of Grass code: [try it](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEETv@xVz1INFvAj9A/HgrTmHZpWCJpDUzaX/HtuKTaoOBN6Qndm9eR1CSg9EpdT0VBTSk4tv7vKPWkZKM8MoIbsqaYsSV7DJLMDGup5rBBb2@o7W2cDts@@E0QRoz7ict8RzJmvZ/XNJQX98xADaZdGnFEcq@xfhsKeqqohOVzToAiyzYVOTrA8aJ7/yGGMpvQA). This change didn't affect the size of the polyglot.
This change allowed to move Commercial (70), ORK (179) and Prolog (186) to be closer to similar languages.

Comment: Its nice to see new practical languages in the polyglot. In what way is this incompatible with adding Milo's Wierd?

Comment: @Potato44 Milo's Wierd doesn't like the space at (2,2) – it tries to turn right (subtract) and [fails](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOjoK6nrmCnkJaZk/pfmUv5vx6Xfn5BiX55ZmpRin5KZmJOajKUp5tblqGflJmH4EF0AQA) with stack underflow. Other Wierd dialects just do nothing in this case.

Comment: This was an absolute pleasure to read. I still poke my head in on the polyglot from time to time, and it just warms my heart to see the parts I contributed come up. Pascal is a great addition. Congrats!

Comment: @Chance Thank you. Glad to hear from you, I was wondering if you forgot about this challenge or not.

Answer (score 8):

## 43. [reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular/wiki/Operator-Reference), 926 bytes

```
#  4"16" 3//v\(@#/;\D"14"<;n4
#/*`3 afaaZ">;[77*,68*,@;'1,'1,q)(22)S#   ␉␉␉␉ (
#yy␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=␉z
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#␉<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][<<<]>+.---.>][
#px%>~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.R␉>]|
#[#yy#yy0l0vx01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111P0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00x1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100(^_)
#|␉
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13   ) )-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#mmeeaeueewuuw*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(  ) /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<␉>//
#
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACLEGEREEX,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  a>>>
#>27.say# /7Jn~49c53c'43'p;|  
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17) #/*23!@^_^_LEnd!]/*///Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVnLdttIkl0Lv1CbNMgyAZJ4kJTlBwhasi3XcZWrymPZnjkmKSkJJklYeLDwkCjJ0pntzJlF73szy/6P3vZX9I9U30jwJYlyddEimMiMjIi8ERkZkf69RB/2Lg7Ox0GcsUykGRsm/qlITPbinO1yP33UbCmKpEriYe750ZhlE8H8aJpnbOQHIlU8nrEOm865mNRgJZYIPizIlFGcMJrCwpOA@cybTtkg4BPTA1kahzSUiWSaCDxTFgkxZOlUeP7I96QIJmaZiFI/jlKT@d4JO/ODgA1FgAkruV4dzFiernUVUkxlGCsMH296S8vlW1mAJhKLlYopT@RKYzaVy14s@Czh0ymUVErsAIpnfihS5meVlAme@gQfpqQiGkqQpktgY8aj9VWyU58zDn3zRPJORZJheabkyyYiEWDJSfg44SHTzhI/AwSE4R57J3jCPiRC6JAC7EXq8Sn0uCESwmKSkNFCTGmjdruy/@vrCmxVzDD5NFNKSevDf/yocGa6rHzk4OuqqqPs//KKXZZ71IYWYAZ7ThON68y9ZqnV6wl8Z42BNU6uFHBVgErArHiaWeDMkwzqrVrGadOcBmtiWfuWJdb8p6AawhbsTcQ@1eW6vDxJBLRYQcpPsOQgjsZAE0tN8ojQiNiODQN4cTRM60ycArM4KiwUn0l8P0x8mCwlg/AB4OEeIV/4voQT3g/Pm@O5kJvGQS7pMDPNyP2ACaYSxzcj9omNuB/QFIwTq0LrRKR5kNGcPBqS3UM/EkOTLdTw4iERhfEpxHEwlR3YLuHaJpNKgRhmiOVSaeiff/nrcDwGnz3Pi5Ph3Fk/sWHs5SEU5lJZDkckd40jHki1QFcn6cV0CDjlgT/kGYmPzucipBJS6lmcB0MWQ2By5mNjTfgpNuNoJLxMFC4e5xl0rLOQnxShwS/8FgsP@QCGlQKkbLlsg@2@hJU8UTiMEebZ6AkzpvusklqH2vNn2vMHPQHddFOvli1r7MDbzKrswlvlW47zaW9lT4XcZ4@NxBkLeDTO@RhLjCNM4J4nptkcW2CUZkDv9gaRncZ8t5vpRCnv3pYsvX4eB9ZkkF8WO3G@dzkB4sVhCGMYAezPeDKWNmJDPwGSwflt6SA4vSVcPSaSGwocq/eosAhZ8HAxE16ewRCizs4mvjdhZ1K7qDBlsW9ui0fXunQ4ozFaiiZlGp2HTcW0ll2kxr0sDDL0XT6IB8Sqc6ND@sR6R7FAxOQDOg/gxIsATJtkdUgs1w4wfqTwkojfcoCLveqPIyLh0TJ4r/m3n0YVbHg/9YEQhWEfIx/e/Eq7@j9FcRIBoyIirW/JGOcSps/DLA0sAFOEN4mZEbHKXAdNlVHxC9Sy0sSTDWPtKFB1E2hphJocWjD6Uhyst8Mi69ylkyIrddZV1X4dkShIYe4oDwK85JHcD5rQL@EXnkhTE86NbWvSmQLt1JrQr24SZpMkPmPiSncqm8TBIm8iP4M5/Ava9BRJPYSdPOBZEaG8OAfeS6tg53PXLgz5AVi9RdRmb30E3HiEGL86@2WmMKNTrqeo0/NsEketm06vrkaaxXHzyQo5NvD0fHMgUNdZyQk/@9FJTLpZ4aJ1ZJuNRzdYIFO5O3PkpxP5uEF6R627I3J2Gg5G8rGBICKXvIWzHAjjKC6EAyE/4tZ7@WNiY2/S4Ob@uSH@hYCJx8J42rIGfmQNxOg@ytcvXryRNKPBwL@PCDBQQrb43UCW5INNKA14OrkTX9kNnD/kSRYYQyujX/GP/x4C77vWmPDzFEfwybJxFIkzsowxutc486n0Ih@bDfklD5Ce/QEPj9Oxy4NlYzOvZ@y9gLfjWIxkVgZNgwDbGJAh0Nx1Z@yEIB@Kxe9mphLDm2G6mB35oQFf3jFtaUC80tEzpRz6Hi63zpqCDWUrSRDzoVXkj75YWbTAXsz4OI7OrbVAZiaDf0PVxXHAVgljNsmzvHhSlvhHtvOn9P3WFpxT2o/2XjT25z/30EOJnft8t9g2CaKL8TrgJ9aAmkcjNDcvtVhM4o@Rki5@7yMTqQw8xiCOT4yiDEgtnNBIlKbcE9J6q9eNfvUzTvkAlcDBLx8P3n3TwaREcEuC4rmR3ZvIw@kXZX/MCTAE8vFnPFM6iscDuGercE4q5Iw1HP1byAd8cE6Vx@TPOxlJHddqzIhXBcOqTpxO75/keZsnFZWknOfFSIDFHx1LOFv8EMttDtea9zqNHxs4sKKUdmqSFp42ygHQhuDETzkzvICncI1sjq44hTXk41u@TEeIRz6zam3EUx7U72VBtcxjUU0VdSD6/GSe96fL0rq0GmURRzqKk53aixzAKUqDdCIrClQAQ4Skj5EvczFUMEUiXGcDZFcy/P/9b8N5oTUWWcpCP0W6MY7oagDZ7iQ@e17InUvfQ8WOHI9YwMWDIlkzXu6x9MzPvElRXiGp@fj6wxPKUAZicUGBl3cUitaUKJaNoRFUQHEkk/VCmWEsiu0xl7uctViTh0IxjNiZP8wmSHwOfNQ6QCtZZv3QJCGyKEti2l519oYNBe09mWt@yZEWBYgKMsMlTf7@N@bxVCbrYAat0V6IlyXqmkQGUzfkdYNX5GALJhciieckGmGM5CgHIufY3KLo15k34ZQ00eWPsajSSExRqb3cO2AGyjS6YKGizfFHWnnv/Q@funbfvWahhYPaoiRT4qZ@bzxupGqdLUicK4G0dH3YxvBqtMLU8kydL4uKeVm7Ln2q8DemUVuaa1FehfIeQLqdOJPlFaBF2U@5HxXYyOnTDK@6ZK3hZA@RthsHGXtEt08CUKBV3Bgwus@BJEnKyjP2lU3ISQyPNR7ZeCuQCKhaDd1VQrWew1qvxCCXkf@0aTZbrlxH@chtd2QrEcOYStruYW/Yt9IFHL3e7Hu7OSO8Hlq0W/Z/eXVZNjv2168pP1fVq0qhPxJvL/GlP66l3GbhDprGazVdX7vJ2p8hqsBr6EZB3ggodLtFmMZ5dqNKxS6ZFPUUiqylI6TL2oh0H5EbBwCEkn55LqWECCPUTbYXpHC74RB4Ds4zUdQARTm0rInUEitzcxkU6kxViDZ171a3QPsMsdg7LiaXJZ3knG66OugJ659/@WtxXdDL0P6feXuE9v8V7UOLULLu3CEUOi6hIVg@vXnHUuxtcUv/ZT/Tup@AD0AFOGR@sricL5K@Nsmy6TPLouA2joORKdNTMQOucBgTGZn1W063MfBOa@fRznYD2Y8wThcMZXk4plypYKjrz5jKlIGHCrvNVBSCgXB3nAITq8wPW6pyx7Jr2YN/I5LPbbIBRAas/n8DhhHa/1u0uz3buO5vuonZgOIypfgQn4go/cY9g5ERhX@xfuPgz2ev3TgsuhArtPYN6XpxGbKyllpuqJCx4uspd1LRdaGLo38pYn3m3aUt9g2gnefCONvochNUL7HJ/ewZ2/1JRJE4ZxrMGPLknPEcCUKi1xcX6/XlZdhdi@xXLoMYhi5bjowezhXAP@6xXtYb9SKygHNufWeZlnOplQP33IK76R2tPHEbtVa1VitHVa0cGQ1df/iQgs5VOXXLR6ZqqjMQGeVAdxAVtDJ3y5FT5m2tPHSbVTkDr4gjl5hwnVrmZZlfWeWHcII6ehJBXiq0cqrT0WKbZuMK@n2J/ahs1UM@vdRUps7oapXEl/1ajXQwy0ekwLXVO6hBc/jUgSVDnTPfltY4dKS3V2551e@/lxjbVhs7KmtZ1mlP2y1ZTu@V2thW2060rZSs6nGL8RHnn9WO0338uFrfeVKt7zqVRh1/v@las6kfgAfbwodpSun8fMtp7TzYVUrH7WO2pZTcrQul1O7X2l2zY/Q7XaW01abwOXtfo0/3VadWfN7i2zb6XezCfqdmGoZhdvogn86@71xfX9e2atfVLMuq5kwpverMPlpGm2bpSum9pDbM91ud/lel1IUS@LMD@3RmN04aJ2j5M/vLzJ7Yk8aw0Wi8s8VHezCzB3bcGOIp8M@eoenbo5k9tiM7ajRmdoyGN7M9NEZ4jmloBCZf8M@3beJNIk7toCE/tq0dHkGfr1uKRFvTxCkPNLXRmzVHTVVHmNee6vCLRguI6Uw3NJtC/7Z@2Gi3tZ1Heqej7TR1kFS03iX@rnR6dDW9r1@hUfzpldL2jvak9nT@z32gl0j8V9dyG1Zz2525T7vtcm23Zuzi43Zq7fnP85IE1uxbytHRq70Pe0dHbqNkWUrJ7Jlqo6lWt8g0jjzZ40CYQTxmrPVUUfEhOncgxn60RTPCUAguciHO8vysio6hGOGo2rpgLMXGRoZa8SpG47naeqI@U1uPVaWE3U9Vd5vuJ2Jz0lHobkkjJCxioOnHpeNepWpdUvKrXejOlVWtHB8r5QoRVqRYoxVvx6Vyuay0O2pL/dVsb3WoX3Hp/4VwhuOFlJXqlux@ScarJlap9bqv917WG22j1JSNg48vSvT2aPXaxGuLXt/u/7D/fn//v@qNd2/39w72f3jzaf/ju6KtM8Y7nY5S6jQfm0ggSsx6/GN0vf3Ue9TyKtutytT5ihyy9OS74XjsN7873vra@LpTtqxKpfmIMbdUOEfjsQ5tq83Wg93Do8Ojt/vR8EEfQFjW52az@fTpU7W587tlfSviY3QZDlE1JWkeboqHe4n/M6c8IlrGRDR@zhF@l0ZhZJXAH5BZbvQVllrvkv/nhT6F9JImpAYycK8ukxtWpWuPbl9nlzJz8kdMo1GcaY0i0aIP8rk8iZjtKAUR1cbOsgkp5EXMJQLqpHio@W7DYX6bmOEXYXQugT6LGTWXmoGINKmF39edJc1Skw5mr@myNr9WK8ivCrWK9XjhsFh2MbZ8hXohVT6eNp@t3yJA8g2aSs@uzJf57ywD57i25FBnf3oZt@bjxNAXa5IqrAbn/StTXCnVrB46Ci27OnWUnzRPv6STzLkOHz70DqfdsO/ooZvRb60WOlfKieYXJNXMDV2j4UyhrJN1azW/74b6T9pUKh@6Noghmzin@uXS0pE7N1eq1y@6kXEd9euvu1Gt0a/n9epn96LOXbs@wxew1YP6bwBvAaWWuRe1yOFtfOlQvYHE1E1r3LnRRVNOtMC96PK@a@tOgIm12mssBnqm3aBW6@sQHmDw7kQnePiQ14LOzAkMQyeqw9bz190MjX7NpfdnGm/Pnl90c8x/puHXhZhAh/KYd9MG4Af9HGBcmG@leqHjjNSbQb3Qdaufn1c/V90HDy66MyPs1wv4n9krw5PyM1J@3Ue06ud1x5KQyIJIU7/3n31vVlOm1uF9ALk@XZtZaFj9jJHpajdc/Qs)

VIP Score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): 0.01164 (snippet in answer 40 checks this for all answers)

### Rundown

This program prints **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.

### State of the Polyglot

This answer marks the 3rd best VIP score so far. We’re making our way back from the byte inflation in the early 30s and within striking distance of the top.

I made one small change to the Test Driver this round to add the number of languages used so far. @SnoringFrog removed the "terrible hack" @ais523 used to get the byte count to simplify calculating the current VIP score, which is now output in markdown following the polyglot.

### Reticular Explanation

Reticular is a D2 language which follows the same path as Reng and Haystack – meaning that it reflects up from line one’s first `/` and wrap around to the bottom and hit a `/` on the second to last line to continue to the right across this code `7Jn~49c53c'43'p;|`.

`7Jn~` is the Reng code, which terminates on the `~`. Haystack’s code used to be `15o|`, but `o` is an output command in both Haystack and reticular. Fortunately, Haystack and reticular both had other output commands that were mutually exclusive so Haystack was changed to output character codes for ascii values 49 and 53 using the `c` command and reticular was set to print the string 43 with the `p` command.

Reticular’s code terminates with `;` while Haystack still terminates with `|`. You’ll notice that Haystack terminates after passing through both its and reticular’s code. This is because `|` is a reflector in reticular so it has to appear after reticular has ended.

#### Fusion Breakdown

When I first worked out this answer I was working towards outputting #41, but since I went with BF for #41, I had to change this to output 43. For some reason this change caused Fusion to gain a trailing space. The fix was to swap the `␉` and `*` in `#.\."12"␉*`. I have no idea why Fusion’s output changed based on this value but I do know that the fix causes Fusion’s reaction to end 1 turn faster.

#### Incident & Hexagony

The Fusion change caused a new Incident token to pop up: `␉␊` and eliminated another token that only appeared in the second half of Incident. The new token also had one instance before the main Incident/Whirl string, which added another layer to Incident’s new imbalance.

My first half of my solution was to eliminate the `###` token which would leave only one “incidental token” in early half of the polyglot. Second I added a token by removing a token from the de-tokenizing string which had 3 instances on the right. This turned out to be `"3"`.

This balanced Incident, but left Hexagony in a difficult place to work with. I’d either have to add bunch of place holder characters to push the Hexagony capsule into the correct location, or shave off enough bytes to place the capsule in a safe location on the next line up in the hex.  My go to move for shaving bytes is removing pieces of the detokenizing string, and after poking around I realized that the `int` in C/C++’s code could just be golfed off, which eliminated the `int` token’s need for detokenization. So `int main()  /*/` became `main(  ) /*/` (spacing deference given to Prelude). Also, I found that I could move `z` from the detokenizing string up to the `x` I placed above the BF family plot. So `#=␉x` became `#=␉z` and Hexagony’s module was able to fit just prior to the polyglot’s emoticon:  `^_^`.

#### Cards on the Table

I’ve decided I wanted to go a little more open source with my research into possibilities to add to the polyglot, so here are a couple languages I’ve touched on that I think are a good place to investigate.

**Octave** is my next favorite language to add. This is appears to require it’s print statement on a new line, rather than immediately following a comment, so I believe it has to go in the Python’s literal string. From what I’ve seen it can be worked in if you overcome the use of curly braces for block comments and Japt’s dislike for them. Japt you’ll remember thinks that curly braces inside strings contain code. And most of Japt’s code is hidden in a string. I have found experimentally that Japt will allow strings to nest within these curly braces though (for example: `` `string{`nested string`}string` ``), so I suspect there is an answer somewhere here, but my test indicates that the string gymnastics used in this line will have to be reworked ``` #()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'`` ``` and I don’t know if this is possible.

<strike>**Del|m|t**</strike> EDIT: @ais523 pointed out that this language is newer than this challenge, and is therefore not allowed. I'll leave my comment  here anyways in case someone goes through this thread looking for future polyglot ideas.

Del|m|t is also on my list as a possible answer, but I haven’t managed to get as far with this one. I have figured out that the below commands are likely the ones you’d use to produce a correct result and terminate the program ([example](https://tio.run/nexus/delimit#@x@lYKIQqQAh7f//BwA)). It has not been proven that it can be worked at all given the rigidity of the top two lines. Del|m|t is also hard very to work with, so if it is worked in it I think it would be best to add another special output from the Test Driver for debugging.

- Z       Push the ASCII values of the next token backwards onto the
  stack. Do not execute that token.
- Y       Pop a. Print the character with ASCII value
- ?       End the program.

Good luck!

Comment: How. Does. This. Work?

Comment: @ckjbgames This truly is the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything. All I can say for certain is the answer is 42.

Comment: Depends on the language. It could be anything in `range(1,43)`

Comment: @ETHproductions Oops! Thanks. This is #43. I guess that makes my Douglas Adams joke fall flat.

Comment: Sadly, #42 is in evil.

Comment: The "terrible hack" is just using the fact that `wc` prints the filename if given a file. For just the number we could use `wc -c < polyglot.poly`; I'd toss that in a var, `echo $bytes bytes`, then you'll have the number for the calculation

Comment: I tweaked the driver to include the VIP score. Was just going to link it in a comment but the driver link is too big for that, so I used an edit and also added the relevant description change.

Comment: Assuming we keep the byte count constant, we'll beat the first place VIP score at language 47. So, without some standout golfing, it'll be a hard fight to beat that 0.009185 score. Max number of bytes entry 44 can have without regressing is 992 though, so it should at least be easy enough to not get worse.

Comment: @SnoringFrog Yeah, I think the main challenge will be to find enough languages that can be worked in, but we can get there with volume for sure.  For example, last I checked Cubix was a cheap, easy add. I've held off on it though because it's difficult for maintenance - like Hexagony. But as we approach the endgame, maintenance becomes less of a concern.

Comment: Del|m|t actually postdates the challenge, so we won't be able to use it. This challenge has been going for that long, now…

Answer (score 8):

## 44. [alphuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alphuck), 954 bytes

```
#  4"16" 3//v\(@#/;\D"14"<;n4
#/*`3 afaaZ">;[77*,68*,@;'1,'1,q)(22)PS#   ␉␉␉␉ (
#yy␉;36!@
#`<` ␉
#=␉z
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#␉<
###xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][<<<]>+.---.>][
#px%>~~~+␉+~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++L)
#R+.----.R␉>]|
#[#yy#yy0l0v01k1k0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100(^_)
#|␉
print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13   ) )-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'(\{(\{})(\{}[()])}\{}\{}\{})'#46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)#1111|=/=1/24=x=9[<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>+.--.]/
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"*␉
###; console.log  39
""""#//
=begin␉//
#seemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeecisajjappppp*/
#define␉z  sizeof 'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(  ) /*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z);}/*'``
$'main'␉//
#-3o4o#$$$
<>"3"O.<␉>//
#
=end   #//
"""#"#//
#0]#echo 21#/(\[FAC,1<-#2FAC,1SUB#1<-#52FAC,1SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,1PLEASEGIVEUPPLEASE)  a>>>
#>27.say# /7Jn~49c53c'43'p;|  
#8␛dggi2␛`␉|1|6$//''25  =#print(17) #s^_^_LEnd!]/*///@!32*<>ssZ222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#lVnLdttIkl0Lv1CbNMgyAZIA@LDlBwjasi33cT09lu05xyQtJcEkCQsPFh4SJVk6vZ05s@h9b2bZ/9Hb@Yr@kZobmXxJolxdEAkmkJERkTciIyNSv5foYm@T8GwSJjnLRZazURqciNRmL87Ycx5kD1ttTZNUaTIq/CCesHwqWBDPipyNg1Bkms9z1mWzBRebGqzEUsFHikwbJymjISw6DlnA/NmMDUM@tX2QZUlEXblIZ6nAPWOxECOWzYQfjANfimBinos4C5I4s1ngH7PTIAzZSIQYsJbr18GMFdnGKyXF1kaJxnD5sxtarp7KAjSxWM5UzHgqZ5qwmZz2csKnKZ/NoKRWYgdQPA8ikbEgr2RM8Cwg@DAkE/FIgjRbAZswHm/Okp0EnHHoW6SSdybSHNOzJV82FakAS07CJymPmHGaBjkgIAz32FvBU/Y@FcKEFGAvMp/PoMc1kRCWkIScJmJLG3U6lf1fX1dgKzXC5rNcK6Xt9//xg8aZ7bHyoYuvp@uutv/LK3ZR7lMbWoAZ7DlLDW4y74plTr8v8J03h84kvdTAVQMqIXOSWe6AM09zqLduWSctexZuiGWdG5bY8B9FNYIt2JuYfazLeflFmgposYaUH2PKYRJPgCammhYxoRGz3QYM4CfxKKszcQLMklhZKDmV@L6fBjBZRgbhQ8DDfUJe@b6EE94Pz1vguZSbJWEh6TAyy8n9gAmGEsc3Y/aRjXkQ0hD0EyuldSqyIsxpTBGPyO5REIuRzZZq@MmIiKLkBOI4mMoXWC7RxiKTSoEYZkjkVKnrX3/7@2gyAZ8930/S0cJZP7JR4hcRFOZSWQ5HJHdNYh5KtUBXJ@lqOASc8DAY8ZzEx2cLEVIJKfU0KcIRSyAwPQ2wsKb8BItxPBZ@LpSLJ0UOHess4scqNATKbzHxiA9hWClAypbTttjzl7CSL5TDWFGRjx8za7bPKpnz2Xj21Hh2ry@gm2mb1bLjTFx4m12Vr/BU@ZbjfNxb21Mj99ljY3HKQh5PCj7BFJMYA7jvi1m@wBYYZTnQu7lA5EtrsdrtbKqVn9@ULL1@EQc2ZJBfqpW4WLucAPGTKIIxrBD2ZzydSBuxUZACyfDspnQQnNwQrh8RyTUFjvQ7VFiGLHi4mAu/yGEIUWen08CfslOpXaxMqdbNTfF4tSkdzmiNV6JJmWb3fkuzndUrUuNOFhYZ@jYfxANi1b32QvrE5gs1QcTkA9oP4MTLAEyLZL1JrOYOMH6g8JKK3wqAi7UaTGIi4fEqeG/4d5DFFSz4IAuAEIXhAD3v3/xKq/o/hdqJgJGKSJtLMsG@hOGLMEsdS8A04U8TZsWsstDB0GVU/AK1nCz1ZcPa2Ap00wZaBqEmu5aMvqiN9WZYZN3bdFJkpc56uj6oIxKFGcwdF2GIhyKW68EQ5gX8whdZZsO5sWxt2lOgnV4T5uV1wnyaJqdMXJpuZZs4rfQmDnJYIzinNU@B1EfUKUKeqwDlJwXgXhkFC597DWXH94DqJwRt9lOAeJuMEeLXW79MFOa0yfU1fXaWT5O4fd3n9XVPS@02H52IY/3OzrbHAX2TlRzwcxAfJ6SbEy1bhw27@fAaCyQqt0eOg2wqb9dIb6l1u0eOzqLhWN62EMTkkTdglh1REidKOBAKYu68kz821vU2Da4vn2viXwhYeCKsJ21nGMTOUIzvonz94sUbSTMeDoO7iAAD5WPL3y1kaTHchtKQZ9Nb4ZVdw/l9keahNXJy@hX/99cR8L5tjSk/y7ADH68ah7E4JctY4zuNsxhKD/K23ZBfihDZ2R/w8DntujxcNbbzesreCXg7dsVYJmXQNAyxigEZ4sxtd8ZKCIuRWP5uZyoxvB6l1eg4iCz48q7dkAbEI@08M0qh7@ByY6tRbChZScOEjxyVPgZibVGFvZjzSRKfORtxzE6H/4aqy92ArfPFfFrkhbpTkvhHtgtm9P3WElxQNh7uvWjuL37uoIcSu3f5rlo2KaKL9Trkx86QmodjNLdPVU0mDSbISJe/d5GJTAYea5gkx5aqAjIHGzTypBn3hbTe@nGrX/2MTT5EIXDwy4eDt990MCkR3NJQ3beyexP72Pzi/I85AYZQ3v6MZ0pH8XkI92wr56Q6ztrAMbiBfMiHZ1R4TP@8k5HUSa3GrGRdL6zLxNns7kG@v32QKiTlOD9B/iv@aFvC3hJEmG5rtNG802mCxMKGFWe0UtNMedq4AEBbghM/4czyQ57BNfIFuuIE1pC3b/kybSE@@cy6tR1PHs6mJP0briA383ey5lqluii4VKmId0G6KA2yVfVdWveymCNjxe5P7WWe4KrqIZvKogNFwghh60McyHQNRY7KletsiARMbhH//MdoUYtNRJ6xKMiQkkxiOj1AQjxNTp8puQvpeyjqkQYSCyyDUOVz1ss9lp0GuT9VFRjyng@v3z@mLGYolmcYeHhL4WpDCTVtdI2hAuonmc8rZUaJULgt5K5GLefko5aMYnYajPIpkqODAOUQ0EpXhQE0SYksztOEcK@zN2wkaH3KdPRLgdQpROSQSTBp8s9/MJ9nMp8HM2iN9lK8rGI3JDK4Q1OeSPgqT1syORdpsiAxCGMkUAUQOYPVhXpvMn/KKbGi8yFrWciRGFXMvdw7YBYqOTqDobrODcZGee/dXz72GgPvikUONnOH8lCJm/699aiZ6XW2JHEvBTLXze4Gute9FaaX5/piWlTvy/J25VPK35hBbWmuZQUWyaMC6XbiVFZggPYEONOBErUz5KJ4NCVrA7t/hMzeOsjZQzqgEoACLXWowOjIB5IkKSvP2Vc2JSexfNZ82MCTQiKkgjby1knXZp7rvBLDQu4OJy271fbkPMqHXqcrW6kYJVT19j73RwMnW8LR78@/b7TmhNd9h1bL/i@vLsp2t/H1a8bPdP2yovRHcu6ngfTHjbTcVu5gGLxWM82Nw679OSIPvIYOHeShgUYHYIRpUuTXClmskqkquVCHrRwhW5VPpPuY3DgEIFQYyL0rI0QYoW6zvTCD241GwHN4lgtVJ6iKaVU26SVW5vYqKNSZrhFt5t0ugIH2KeK1f6QGlyWd5JxtO13oC@dff/u7OlHo52j/16I9Rvt/VPuzQyg5t44ZlI4raAiWj2/esgxrW0084vONOakiCA4WFygZIyB4IgEh8hvTXbMxeh8BJ2wALMlbyEGkOJEOjGmez546DsXCSRKObZnxijnMAP@ykeQ5vxV0vgNndnYf7j5oIqES1smSoSw4J5R@KYam@ZTpTDsJZt7R0Efh3mE66stQeLuuwtEp889t/WilaBm0moqbPYYxGLIegb7uYphR5rWmSUOZ57FKs8IGLkKiMotXNgzZAIlJr2MFB3QxKHZJpKh2FfOcwYPTs@V2gGCMSiginOQp35KRBUaKt6lrt1x3I4UKrm1VC6fb4iUMzvC/W5wkRvu/VbvXb1hXg22nUVvcZJVXvU@ORZx946zFyokiON88dQkWozdOXZavEAyNzjXppjoQWvuXXm7qkLHm62u38vFNocv8ZyVic@TtqS0DA6BdFASwFh3wguololiQP2XPfxRxLM6YAceLOOzJC2RJqVlf/nOhvjoQvG2R/cpFmMDHyo4rw6N7CfCP@qyf98f9mCzgnjnfObbjXhjl0DtzsEDMrlGees1au1qrleOqUY7JRe7fp6h6WYYHHtq6rc9BZJVD00XYg8d65dgt845RHnmtqhyBRwTKCwy4yhz7oswvnfJ9OEEdb1JB60oY5cykvbNh281L6PclCeKyU4/47MLQmT6n42USXw5qNdLBLh@SAldO/6AGzeFTB46M5e4i7jiTyJXrs3Ldq37/vcTYA725q7O245z0jeclx@2/0psP9I4bP9BKTvWozfiY80961@09elSt7z6u1p@7lWYdn99Mo9Uy3x6ACdvBxQytdHa247Z37z3XSkedI7ajlbydc63UGdQ6PbtrDbo9rbTTof1h/q5GV@9Vt6aun/DtWIMe1v@gW7Mty7K7A5DP5t93r66uaju1q2qe51V7rpVedecfHKtDo0yt9E5SW/a7ne7gq1bqQQl8GmHjpNE8bh6jEcwbX@aNaWPaHDWbzXlDfGgM541hI2mOcBf4a0RoBo3xvDFpxI2YiBI0/HnDR2OM@4S6xmDyBX9Bo0G8GydzCAmb8mo0jM@HUOfrjibBNgxxwkNDb/bnrXFLNxHNjScm3KLZBmAmMy2jQRH@gfm52ekYuw/NbtfYbZkgqRj9C3wuTbr1DHNgXqKhPmal9GDXeFx7svjz7pklEv/Vc7ym03rgzb0nvU659rxmPcfldWudxc@zksTVHjja4eGrvfd7h4des@Q4Wsnu23qzpVd3yDKuzFySUNhhMmGs/UTTcRGdNxSTIN6hEZlAZireclEIcVoUp2J1@ciWv3xBDMBVBeVIjLFH75wzlmHBIzWv@BWr@UxvP9af6u1HulZCVKAjiQ4d3iT2tKvRwZtBEDnEwDCPSkf9StW5oKzfODfdS6daOTrSyhUirEh9rHbyICmVy2Wt09Xb@q92Z6dL7zWP/meG5AUPNAs5j1JjUJJxrIXpG/3e672X9WbHKrVk4@DDixI9PVw/tvDYpsd3@3uvfv3wvt58@9P@3sH@X9583P/wVrVNxni329VK3dYjG4lTiTmPfoivHjzxH7b9yoN2ZeZ@Re5cevzdaDIJWt8d7Xxtft0tO06l0nrImFdSTtN8ZLJS9vnw8@FP@/Ho3gAQOM7ze@1WtdPNsk@tVuvJkyd6a/d3x/nWZoDeVaREVZlmRbQtVO6lwc@ccqh4FS7R@LlAZF7ZhZFhwmBIlrn2Thlr85X8lyDeaaSXtCI1UH34dZnYsSodC/UGJruQWWMwZgb1YrtrqiSTLuSyRRqzhqspIjo7cFdNSCFHYh4R0EsKlUbgNV0WdIgZfhFhFxLoWo6oedQMRWxILYKB6a5oVpp0MXpDl43xtZoiv1Rqqfn40UhNW/WtHqFeRFWfbyxGmzcIUHiAptJvVBbT/HemgS3eWHGosz89jRvjsZmYyzlJFdadi/drU1xq1bweuRpNuzpztR8N37ygTc69iu7f9z/PetHANSMvp99aLXIvtWMjUCTV3Is8q@nOoKyb92q1YOBF5o/GTCofeQ0QQzZxzsyLlaVjb2GuzKyf92LrKh7UX/fiWnNQL@rVT955nXuN@hxfwFYP678BvCWURu6d12KXd/Cl/fYaEjMvq3H32isacmyE3nmPD7yG6YYYWKu9xmSgZ9YLa7WBCeEhOm8PdMP793kt7M7d0LJMovrcfva6l6MxqHn0/NTgnfmz816B8U8N/HoQE5pQHuOu2wD8oJ8LjJX51qorHeek3hzqRZ5X/fSs@qnq3bt33ptb0aCu4H/aWBuelJ@T8ps@YlQ/bTqWhEQWg4b@ffD0e7uaMb0O7wPI9dnGSKVh9RN6ZuvVcPn/)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .011199 (snipped in answer 40 calculates this for all answers; to improve, next entry should be no more than 1020 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above. You can test Reng [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) and Modular SNUSP [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html); they output 19 and 31 respectively, as required. Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers. The alphuck interpreter can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master); it outputs 44, as required.

### Driver updates

Since we're paying more attention to the VIP score now, I added in a bit to the driver to calculate how many bytes we can use without regressing in that regard. I also have a crappy Haskell program for the same purpose [here](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#lZDdbtQwEIXv8xRzmS1y0@2WRay6CAm0UiUkEJW4RRNn6kQ4nsV2yK6AZ1/GTihFVCBy4fjnzDnfzOmrggIU7NhDG@N@U1WaGzJs785DRP2JDrpFZ@hcc199HijEjl2olheXq2cXFTaNQmVFMKAhFVlOe7ZHYzkm21do9WAxUoDYEgTNnuDOc/9fYeun66tlJQbqC/mAsbOkOhfJkFd7n3Ye0DWgf6W1PEKP7gj1MR01OqgJBJcaiJxhHB2ilIVRqscutjzEfP/h5t0MaijGzhkY2QdK7aiXt44l0Ow8G7n4XhRKJf1t1pf3eDDjwYy3KCbHzQbK94R2ZxklfAHbF4Cg7pdZZqGGLdRVac/OVosU0uMhtyLG2hMKTl93/7RLSxaybT7O1jLfME2lAPm@PXi7hj80CSP91fKnWkbkxy6QvDzmXGb5k6VQ99g5UTWcS6fnawWC37xxif3mLbzmobaUBVPeXwSW4oO4LTzeUJ44lL@zlVklVJNwUZxOV6vi@eX6Bw) because this seemed like as good a time as any to force myself to learn a tiny bit more Haskell.

### alphuck explanation

I thought "hey, maybe one of the umpteen [brainf*** equivalents](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Brainfuck_equivalents) uses an output command we haven't used much!" Didn't have to get far down the list to find one that worked.

The commands `aceijops` equate to bf's `><+-.,[]`.

Aside from the `P` in line 2 and the 3 `s`s in the last line (one a bit before, and two after the Hexagony capsule), most of the new code is mixed in with the evil code.

The worst part of alphuck was finding [the interpreter](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master). I had actually given up, deleted my answer, and was in the process of searching for a replacement bf-derivative when I stumbled across this great compiler. Sadly, this means we can't test alphuck on TIO, because this compiler has some quirks that mean a trivial alphuck to brainfuck tranpilation doesn't work. Namely, cells are plain `int` and thus aren't constrained to 8 bits; also, this compiler treats the language as case-insensitive. Fortunately, this differences only cost me a few bytes in the end.

#### alphuck interpreters (not usable for this challenge)

Also, for future challenges, I wrote a couple alphuck interpreters today (Feb 23, 2017) on TIO. One is [case-insensitive](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#bU7BigIxDL3PVwQ8jKIzRQVPizgMFfSiMEf1ELtRU6UtbV1Y2H@ftYriwYS8l5e8w2s7qQAv7nRVZ2ATyTvyN4SuwkAFm0AmcOQf6sH@F2aNsZ7Nce7tEbojMRqL4aSXKYzwB9FDob4hR0WsrQtVLRfL1brJH78P93z61d8W5WCzey05TJ95ysSZsC6KyLaIHk1wfCEfxN4jm0PK/O5tWyIpiWiNku6dBNUcKp1VdBfS4cOURi0aZJ0pxZr0Pw) and the other is [case sensitive](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#bY7RS8MwEMbf81cc@NAN7YoTfNBRrO5qC6ODJhuI@pDFOBNHGpIoCP7v3eqYVvQHd8fdd/B97VEH8I19eROvoEyQzkq36zAQ3MvYS@NVUO9yCKsPuKKmccqsc9esYTBOxmfJ6fmQCB7gE4KDWDwBF1Lpxvr9JTqsEUTp5PghHp3cP6aTCNKD6aibJGlsSIJq4uC48VZtpPPJynFlnrtg/d@2lXsslz2E8lwT/o/WKUoTIZSWmpCeovkOAEIYUlZWt3CTUQSKFS1ZuSzZ3SXQYr6YTaHIlgjTMs@xxopBjXQxYxRYkVVwjfm8xguC3774VfgrFv7EQvwTaws) (assuming the lowercase used on the esolang wiki is the intended case).

### Minor golfing and fixes

I got rid of the excess `m` from evil. Then, to prevent `m` from becoming an Incident token, I replaced one of the filler `x`s in the main Incident string with an `m`.

I tried changing some of INTERCAL's `FAC`s to `DO`s but that just created alternating messes in Fission and Incident, so now they're all back to `FAC`. I was able to swap `LEGEREEX` for `READOUT` though. The best resource I could find to look up which Latin words INTERCAL supports is [here](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/intercal/blob/8a65e8ba1cc65870b0d6b1bb174a4c4560bde07f/src/lexer.l). Hoped to find some help for avoiding P and S in there, but no luck.

Hexagony is back to it's right to left capsule, which is one character longer in order to keep Perl happy, but it let me golf a bit more.

Side note: The three `s`'s in the final line can be moved around pretty freely. Comes in handy for fine-tuning Hexagony placement.

#### Where to go next

@Chance suggested Octave in answer 43 (and gave some help/reasoning, so look there for that) and mentioned Cubix in a comment.

If you want to continue being as uninventive as me, I'm sure there's more bf equivalents that are simple to drop in. Just make sure there's an interpreter that predates the challenge *before* you write it (on that note: the interpreter/compiler I used also supports ReverseFuck, BinaryFuck, ZZZ, Ook!, Blub, There Once was a Fish named Fred, TrollScript, VerboseFuck, and WordFuck)

### Warning

@Chance's first 45th answer used an extra `s` after the bulk of the alphuck code, removing the need for one of the ones at the end of the program. If READOUT is switched back to LEGEREEX for INTERCAL, this works, but causes alphuck to parse most of the last 3 lines of the program (from `UB#2` onwards). Currently, this Just Works™ despite all the loops that are involved (most are escaped by convenient `a`'s (equivalent to brainf***'s `>`), but it's worth keeping an eye on. Worst case, you can add another `p` to the evil/alphuck line to open a new loop and add an `s` near the end of the last line to skip everything.

Comment: Does Incident still work? It's not balanced with the usual 1:8 token ratio.

Comment: @Chance Fixed, and I managed to shave off a byte somewhere while fighting with Incident/INTERCAL/Fission, so I'd say it worked out.

Comment: The case-insensitive Alphuck interpreter doesn't actually accept uppercase. You might want to fix that for future challenges (obviously, it doesn't affect the polyglot itself).

Comment: @ais523 Fixed, and added input to each to verify they're what they say they are now

Answer (score 8):

## 52. [COW](https://esolangs.org/wiki/COW), 1150 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPZ (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDOiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][
#x%+>+=+~tt .
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix@O6O4/0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
'\';echo 50;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.\."12"__*'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///89^_^_Z222999"26
```

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

Want to learn more? Try the [polygot chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpLc9tIkj4P/kJfyiDbBEgCIEhJlkyClmzLs@5ut7SW7IkwSUsQWCRh4dUAKFGW6djrbuxh7nPZ4/yPue6vmD/S@2UV@NDL3X2YiKUsolCVlZmVr8pM@dcSfdhhHFyNgzhnOc9yNkz9C56a7PkV23X9bLPZUhQBlcbDqedHY5ZPOPOjZJqzkR/wTPHcnHVZUmAxacBKLOXuUIIpozhltIWF5wHzmZck7CxwJ6bHAl/AZnFI6zlPk5TjO2MR50OWJdzzR74n6DA@y3mU@XGUmcz3ztmlHwRsyANsWBH36kDGptnalCRlKsNYYfh4yS1Wl29lDpiIL47LEzcVx41ZIs6@OPVl6iYJmFRK7AiM537IM@bnlYxxN/NJhtiS8WgoJJUspRszN1o/JbvwXeaC32kqcGc8zXE8U@BlE55yoHSJ@Dh1Q6Zdpn4OEZAg99ghd1N2nHKugwoUwDPPTcDHDZIgFhOFnA5iCkV1OpX9g1cVKEzuMN0kV0pp6/jff1BcZjqsfNLGr6OqbWX/55fsutynMbgAMig1STVXZ85Xlln9PsfvzD6zxulcAVYFUgmYFSe5BcxumoO91ci4aJpJsEaWdW5pYs2IJNQQumCvI/a@Ls7lTdOUg4uVSN1zHDmIozGkiaOm04ikEbGtBhTgxdEwqzN@AZnFkdRQfCnkezzxobKMFOKeQTyuR5KXDiDECReA5RXyXNDN4mAq4LAzy8n8IBNsJYyvR@w9G7l@QFuwTqgk1ynPpkFOe6bRkPQe@hEfmmzBhhcPCSiML0DOBVIxAZ8J1zxNMAVgqCEWR6Wlf/71b8PxGHj2PC9Oh4WxvmfD2JuGYNgVzLowRDLXOHIDwRbg6kRdbgeBCzfwh25O5KOrgoRgQlC9jKfBkMUgmF76cKyJewFnHI24l3Np4vE0B491FrrnMj740m5x8NA9g2IFAUFbHNtguy@gJY9LgzHCaT7aZkayzyqZ9VF79lR79qjPwZtu6tWyZY3bsDazKqbwVvmW4bzfW@mTrOfYj8mLgmQyRczASpQliCYpCdNzcZyMgkqOmFdnZ0LQIhLB0IWLXvJKytkZ/HpxMGEj0gZov0F@W2BY6XQBd9PE@HDNwmCdMLI8uxMkgvgShAVvFDhh0xERd8cuSOXFgfbkgSRFMXPzaOcRLJ2wnXG2bZz50A7ZAUJNoYy1MwK81ZQwwCa1t@YUoXsFLJ4M0StNMn8EJYew2/SKeZycAV7BZZwjIlNhGJkPO4pHrGE0Nzd/Q/l5au0ZHyzX@Gx9U8d0@Ftq3mMjfskCNxpP3TEMOY6wxfU8nuSFB@EkWQ4fuR0GxaRRxHQzmyjl3du0RWwrov0aDYo@UntFhHbJ7CGoEKI2Ang5c9Ox8EQ29FP4S3B1mzoALm4RV08J5AYDp@oDLCwuJhgZn3FvmsPdYMiXE9@bwHaJu0g6rIyOt8ljap06Qo4xWpImZuzu46ZiWsspYuNBFAZp9C4eRH1C1b0xIZS/PvFtzG4W3oM4XrKICLU2a1quCdsrhIbb/IgyCYS/xdUtPGuZXizlCQH/QBdTyn@ZQmGwZ38cEYgbLa/9tcjoZ1EFV4Wf@ZA6XeBk68evD@g@@AuXOQzkLu@y9WAeI6PB9uKCpoWFEhTuTWJmRKxS8KCp4j79BLasLPXEwFhLIlTdhJw0kpdYWiD6JPOy2xcq696FEyQrddZT1UEdd1iQwYSiaRDgZRoJF9O4fg1b83iWmXAYyNakbATcqTWuz28C5pM0vmR8rrcr95H7gwp5MT3zZ/8PNeIRX/Ibp1pTg5j6PXq4A/gvVsQdelDF6wg3F2L6Z3HFRBQyp@E0cHOZZXjxFHJeqgPXjes0pAaPIaOfkHmxn3y6EEfI01b5u0j5Z5Sp9hU1uconcdS6GdLU1UpTpozvrRA3nJlc3X@Zq@uoxIY3fnQeE29WuBidNEx78wYKlBx3d478bCK@boDeYevuitidhWcj8XUPQESmeMvixUIYR7EkDgn5kWu9FQ8TYfs@Dm5Gxxvkn3PoeMyNnZZ15kfWGR89BPnq@fPXAmZ0duY/BAQxUFG1eN4Dlk7P7pMSkqLJnduT3ZDz8TTNA2No5fTk//sfQ8j7rjYm7lWGNPp8OTiJ@CVpxhg9qJxiK72Ir/sV@WkaoMT6DRyeS6mzGywH9@N6yt5yWDuSnEhUVuA0CODIEBkCzF1zhicE0yFfPO9HKmR48xKWuyM/NGDLW2ZDKBCvlFhQevcQlluZhERDFUcaxO7QkjWgz1calbLnM3ccR1fW2pVipme/g9XFZc9WRV8@meZT@U2V3m/pzk/o91suWEA2Nvee2/vF4wF4MLH1kO1Kt0kRXYxXgXtundHwZITh/UeVh0n9McrKxfMhsL8cJa7HrcuMHveazRukaAGK9aOf3x0dftN@BELkbmkgv@9F9zrycKlF@W9jwikD8fVHDE/YgecGsL6WtD3qtRhrYvJvCTZwz66oOTD54zZEVMe1GjPiVQW0auUkycObPO/@TbLZI/Z5MWpU/lu3Dq4OP8Rxm8O14YM24cfGqs7KpCGNqLC8J/a4Fy4zvMDNYBp5IV1@AW2Ir2@ZKt0QHtnMavQtQ73F1KLWfahcWu1MfC/G7Z0INdNLgJeHLrXb2cMKDTXxxNdqK70V9vqSu0O6ar9@02BjL6cq5QGT@R3RSBYIVIKt2YUZPyQ0L76k37vLIrd5K/pIy8IuqxftL8z5adHuyJYdxdJqlUVuKMpdGi/SprasqbOJaKSg9h0iir@LfJG2enEqK0PZfhA35j/@Piz6S2OeZyz0M2Ro44g6oij/JvHlM0m3oL6XJC71pwgH4kYgE1vjxR7LLv3cm8i2Eg777tXxdtETKLqzeDmk8L3GhTw3lkbgwc25KF8lN8OYSxUWhJe7FoeCBU3DiF36w3yCZPHIR5kveg6LOhicpAQW5WlMJlBnr9mQU0ATefmnKVLJII7PRTlAnPzj77ITgkUgA9cYL8iL1twaRQb/sUX7wZN56wLJZ57GBYhGQoYfTCGRKxggl/M68yauaNGkJjMWDQoiI5sUL/aOmLHPKtRYpn5F2x9p5b23f37fawycryy0kNxYlJkLuanfG0/sTK2zBUh7zpHLry83sLxarTC1PFOLY1ETU/TslkYlDY5pNBbqWjQcQtH/FHbHL0XDQXSVInJzaiyi/slyvOoCtWxEOmUNWVGIUsc4ytkmdd85RIKR7Jgy6mdT8UxbyjP2hU3IVgyP2ZsNvEmBBNSvCZ1VLrqe/lsv@dlUXJoXTbPZcsRxyidOpytGKR/G1NHrfexfDqxsIZV@f/Z9ozmD2OIU4I8t8pz9n19el81u48uXzL1iqjqvtEWVpD5VWfn68PXh/tHx3vG7I4hxrhcCPCxa1aLt6hZteNjyNFt4ZiE/6tiLronoutNmgbsst0psr8nqhA8s3BkU1qokU1qjprm1mq6v/QFhf4aAC6OlRq5oxCoLzuKizbjQIpx0ImtfFMRLO8yWZSwdYUReFEARVKeJXCMjTTBSusn2ggxWPxxCjWdXOZdlm6xcl@WrWmJl11yeos5UhWAz5267CVq@xP3qncrNZQEnMGf3dWz73PrnX/8mu7T9HOP/LMYjjP9bjj9aJKW7bT3J41I0JJb3rw9ZhtAiDx66s7UzyZoU9h1NUbqHkOCFEAiBS2ZX513h0XrvIU8oAcIkMyXLFPR4OtAmeZ48tSwKxuM4GJmiAuEz6AGGbSLptn6ZUtMczmRtbW5t2EhwuXGxQCh6MWNKhyVCXX/KVKZc@IlzeuaxTqfDVJT8AXe22lKQVtn92FJPl4yWAavIuN1j2IMtqx1Y6xbbtLJbs3XayhyHVewKG7QRkqVe4NWaGABEp@mokIeKsBEXoqJuAp/lDNacXi3uI1wGqExDkpP408kCkQFEEreuKndsF/xiReS8/o270lxXg/oXAhMZ8lP1PtNhsJD/ucdyIoz/S457/YbxdXBf239pO3t3u/va7d48nYXtHkUxlUGvwCvTmlazZdlb@pqfqAUqcEte8QUo4QfwK4/7n@Ik23ux//qHg8OjO91pAVm5DVZhlW6n1jfMem@wHFTusfllUn8cn4Pjb7RpjZwg/M/rDVu/2E3d0GbXGvILi7pGimktVnC/aJ0bHOuypbx29AUPsN9ipmyrIL4i6Cl30q51bhZZ@ZLo@s67Z16EP9hPUYXCJOlPg9T0wx3hg5PdH3kU8SumwbtCF0brTpG7p3p98bfp@vKvCWsn@beiqL1tc/uV6yCGZ5WttriN2nOY12mf9fP@qB@RjbWvrO8s02pfa@XAubIQFvSuVp44dq1VrdXKUVUrR@QYjx/TJTYvw@9OTNVUZwAyyoHeRrSHnzrlqF12O1p56DSrYgdecT9cY8PXzDKvy@7cKj@Gmdcxk3KKJlwrZzplLA3TtOfg71PsR2WrHrrJtaYydUZ/lCHyZb9WIx7M8gkx8NXqH9XAObzmyBLXZrsIt9Y4bIuoVLlprL/@WrK3GFO1ebP1aFcH8pZlVS/6L3fblZ47apq/eINKSVftDbUdbSglq3rKDs8PDz/AZZr6kdp7pHWfsCfVentru1rHJru@@yd82C9KqfsnaK/b2nq0i8Fp51QpdQa1Ts/sGoNuTyldK6XPc6WklJxZ522NPr2X3Zr87O/9hO@OMeglhz/t7x3t15sdo9R8eVBvHr17XrLxstlcrNAMLbew/nZ/7@XBu@M6hn9@/X7/3eHLA9/3k2w4zIbxZNCtmYbBDJN1B@Bg9n2tW3NqX/OcwdBedmfvLKMDuj8ppbcEaBh93ewOviilXqkHCc2bjaBx0ZjZ5/b5m/hg9e/gAAv@bPdg62DDanyK08akMbGHtm3PGvxd42rWuGqE8YE9xJPjpxFi6DdGs8a4ETUi276B7eF/4UH85iAGqhjb8lkjJ6yNEZ7jg4M3QDYC4U/48RuNBrhsXMzAb2CLz8cTvdHY2NK2azvFj/NIp/Tki1LpF6nUZqPNZ37erkhj0TR@4QaaavdnzVFT1XEJazs6zNpu6bqhNehS3tA/2p2OtrWpd7vaVlPHslqZqXFa0a61a3uu01dPa@gDfY5Rn6YqpXmJ3DhiG5s6rhiuf7Ec22puwBTKtd2asYuP0611isez0lBozrSUk5OXe8d7JyeOXSIylqWUzL6p2k315KRaoeO0KdeNA24GCOytHUXFpwQ454yPQZF2ZBnHJzx0@ZTzy@n0ki8/L1BgffrkJlU4fNuk@NRs7mxvbu@0mtv17Z3tjU17a3Ozbjfr9pPtJzuNut2wt@2t7c0du769sdPa2NjYwermzhOrqpSGfESZeMIyhL54VEkqhv1MbW0jZW09UZUSwiM1BDvUOo3NSVehtjfTmG5VLXIN9bSk9itV65qKTEQ@vT23qhX1VFWAvdO9Lm1tzulAc2VI5frGDh0UnmXPO12MyhXCV6E5oxVvxKVyuQwvfNtVW@qBqTj0/1JoB0lIyAiIStmXeNP@Gv3QLj1NKq2NSt8pyfJDs5/opW7ziYn0uzSQk9oG5gYlYTxNmySbbX83HI/95nfs9Iv9ZatsWZVKc5Mxe4tEur3z8eTjyYcmhLqzoza3frWsb119WF2G/xFHZJyG98X/vdR/41L6Gy3vAAzeTHHdLGXMSMiBf0ZSvjEnBb8@Jf6HDOYU4oskqNEAdatXFzk5q1KDtTfQ2bVI@P0R02gVmYAtCw9ZYuXTNGKNtiKBqE3XXg5BhWyCOQRAkxTuNd@x28zvEDI8cUsUFOiz2FFzaBjwSBNc@AO9vYRZctLF7jVe1vbXahJ8LtmS5/HCoTy2XFu@gr2Q@gWeVuzWbwGg1gJMpd@oFMf8PcdAQqMtMdTZHz7Grf24EPXFmQQLq8VifqWKuVLN62FboWNXk7byo@bp13RRt7@Gjx97H5NeOGjroZPTs1YL23PlXPMlSDV3Qsew2wmYbee9Ws0fOKH@o5YI5kOnAWDQJsyZfr3UdOQU6sr0@udeZHyNBvVXvahmD@rTevWD87nuOo36DL8QWz2o/wLhLUSp5c7nWtR2O/ilnOGGJBInq7ntG1O05VwLnM89d@A09HaAjbXaKxwGfGa9oFYb6CAeYPHuxnbw@LFbC7qzdmAYOkF9bD171csxGNQcen@quZ3Zs8@9KfY/1fB0QCbQwTz23dQB8IG/NmQs1bdiXfI4I/ZmYC90nOqHZ9UPVefRo8@9mREO6lL8TxsrxRPzM2J@3Ua06od1wxIiEf0DTf3ef/q9Wc2YWof1Qcj1ZG2n5LD6ASvJyhvm/wc)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .008178 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1217 bytes)

This program prints **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Cubix’s cube shape viewed [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)
- Incident is checked by keeping the tokens balanced as described in previous answers.
- For Deadfish~, can be tested to output 48 [with this](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.

### Changing spaces

We had 4 instances of ␠␠ in order to detokenize it. I changed `echo␠␠21` to `echo 21` and removed both spaces in `^_)␠␠0046`.

### COW Explanation

As it turns out, most of the Cow interpreters I could find ([these three](https://github.com/BigZaphod/COW/tree/master/source) in C++, K, and C++ and [this one](http://www.frank-buss.de/cow.html) in Javascript) all *irkingly* output a newline with each `OOM` (print cell at int) command. Then, I found an interpreter on a German geocaching tools website that doesn't have that weird quirk, so I thought I was in the clear. Then, I found out that *that* interpreter just fails in weird ways sometimes, so I went back to the first JS one I found. Not being able to use `OOM` on two small numbers cost me ~35 bytes in the end. Ouch. Still came in just 1 byte under the VIP limit for this answer though.

The COW code I ended up with is just the [brainf*** constant](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants) for 52 plus a print.

### Making a mess of the Incident

In a previous answer, we overlooked Incident breaking from `01` becoming a token, which overlapped with `1k`, causing both to not be considered tokens, so I broke up one of the `01`s with an `x` (which was necessary padding to help with Cubix anyways).

COW has been interleaved into the Incident line. It's a mess to read this way, but it let me golf out some of the `x`'s we used for padding, keeping me just barely in the VIP score. However, `mo` itself became a token. To fix this, I replaced Incident's `0o` token with `0mo` and arranged the rest of the COW code around that. The end result is that it's not as easy to move around bits of COW as you would think, because the `0mo` placement is important.

There may have been a better token choice for replacement; I didn't spent a lot of time selecting one. If you're looking at changing that, remember that evil uses `m` as landing points for jumps, and that not allowing `O0` and `o0` to become tokens (or, strategically making them tokens) will be important. I didn't have enough time to work on that puzzle, but if I get some time before another answer appears I might try.

I particularly want to point out this section of the line, where two moos are separated by a zero. It'd be easy to overlook (especially with a font like Notepad++'s, as you can see in the image), and doing so while tweaking things around there could make both COW and Whirl blow up.

[image: moo0moo]

### Appeasing the forces of evil

All of the extra `m`s meant evil's jumps didn't carry it quite as far as the used to, making it parse a lot more characters. Some incident tokens have been renamed to keep evil happy, and two of the `e`s on the evil/alphuck line have been moved to precede the `m` that evil lands on, as evil now parses two `e`s in the Incident line (just before the Cubix capsule). There was also an issue with a lone `x` that was being parsed. I didn't want to replace it with a new filler character, as the Incident line's hard enough to follow as is, so instead I did this:

[image: evil sample]

Switched an Incident token to `0t`, since `t` in evil is "skip next command if accumulator is not 0." The accumulator spends most of it's time not equal to 0, so I figured that was a fair assumption to depend on to jump over the `x`. The second `t` just skips an `m` that wasn't being used anyways.

In general, `b e g p q r u w z` are troublesome characters for evil to parse. `l v x` may also cause issues if not encountered in pairs. If you don't want to construct a more fragile evil program, it's easiest to avoid those.

### Cubix

The Cubix capsule moved a bit.

### Fission

Despite throwing `O` all over the place, Fission never even broke for me. I just want to formally apologize here for the Incident line now being a minefield of Fission output statements.

Comment: Doesn't quite work in Incident. The token `1k` got detokenized because it overlaps with `01` (which also appears three times; this overlap causes neither of them to count as a token). You'll need to break up one instance of `01`, or add an additional such instance.

Comment: @ais523 Weird. Could've sworn I kept the Incident tokens the same as answer #51. Regardless, it's fixed now.

Comment: I constantly amaze myself with how poorly I can perform simple tasks (like copy/pasting a url). lol. That's been fixed as well now.

Answer (score 8):

## 71. [what](//github.com/gimmetehcodez/what), 1877 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@-----x-.+?
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#x}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{}) ){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir "6"
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/* ar  (????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!)
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
#s  8␛dggi2␛`|$// '' 25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_222999 rk:start | print: "69" & s rk:end |6#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005244 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1957 bytes)

## Validation

This program prints **71** in what, **70** in Commercial, **69** in rk-lang, **68** in Python, **67** in C11, **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C99, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtbV9tKln6O/kK/FLJPJGFLsmwggC9AEnImp5MDE0jSK7ZDhCzbCrodScYmxFnzOrPmod/7ZR77f/Tr/Ir@I2e@XSVfAENy1ppZawxIJdWu2tfae9cuc26nw99/L9CHHUf@1cCPMpa5acZ6iXfpJgZ7esX2bS/drNYkiUMlUW/keOGAZUOXeWE8yljf891UcuyMtVicz2JQgxVY4to9ASb1o4TREBZc@MxjThyzc98eGg7zPQ6bRgH1Z24SJy6uKQtdt8fS2HW8vudwPMydZG6YelGYGsxzLtjY833Wc30MWCB3ypiMjdKlVwKVIfUiieHjxLdInT8VXcCE7oxdN7YTzm7EYs77jOtxYscxiJQK7ASEZ17gpszLlJS5duqRDDEkdcMel1Q8l27E7HCZS3bp2cwGvaOEz526SQb2DD4vG7qJiyltQj5I7ICp48TLIAIS5AE7du2EnSauqwELFOCmjh2DjhsogSwiDBkxYnBFNRrK4dELBQoTIww7zqRCUjv9118kmxlNVjyr468py3Xp8Nfn7LrYoTaowGRQapyotsaa31hqdjou/ibWuTlIphJmlSAVn5lRnJmY2U4ykLdo6ZdVI/aX0LLGLU0sGZGA6kEX7GXI3pU5X84oSVxQsRCpfQGW/SgcQJpgNRmFJI2QbVWgACcKe2mZuZeQWRQKDUVjLt/ToQeVpaQQ@xzisR2SvFgAXJxYArC8XJ4zvGnkjzgcRqYZmR9kgqE048s@e8f6tufTEPTTVILqxE1HfkZjRmGP9B54odsz2IwMJ@oRUBBdAp2NSfkLrJlgaaVxogAMNUScVer651//1hsMMM@B40RJLzfWd6wXOaMABNucWBuGSOYahbbPyQJcmbCL4UBwaftez84IfXiVo@BEcKzjaOT3WASEydjDwhral1iM/b7rZK4w8WiUgcYyC@wL4R88YbdgPLDPoViOgOPmbOts/xm05LjCYPRglPW3mR4fMiU1P6p7u@reWscFbZqhrRdNc1CHtRnr/BWelIcM593BQp9kPadeRKvIj4cj@Az0hGkMb5KQMB0b7KTkVDL4vDI754LmngiGzpfo2FUSl51jXc8Y4zYibIDG67Ru8xkWOp3B3TQxt7dkYbBOGFmW3nESfjQGYk4bOU7YdEjI7YENVFnO0IFgSGDkb26ydhHC0mm2c5dt6@cetEN2AFeTK2OJR4DXqgIGswntLS2KwL7CLI5w0QtNMq8PJQew2@SKOS4tBqwKV/g5QjLihpF6sKOozyp6dXPzO8rPEvNA/2Da@hfzQR0T87fUfMD67pj5djgY2QMYchRiiO04bpzlKwicpBnWyG03yF/quU830qFU3L@Nm/u23Nsv4SDvI7SXe2ibzB6CCiBq3ccqZ3Yy4CuR9bwE68W/uo0dAJe3kMufCOQGAZ/ke0iYBSYYmTtxnVGG5QZDHg89ZwjbJepCsWCFd7yNHq@WscPl6P05aiLGaj2uSoY5f0Vk3DuFThq9Ow@8Pk3VuvGCK3/5xcMz22mwYuJoTiI81NJbw7QN2F4uNETzE8ok4P5moZuvrHl6MZcnBPwLBabE/W0EhcGevUFIIHY4D/tLntFLQwWhwks9SJ0CONn66csjigfvXZHDQO4ili078wgZDYbnAZo6ZkqQXGcYMT1kSk6DKvN4@hlkmWni8Ia@lETImgE5qSQv3jWb6LPIy24HVNa6C8dRKmXWluVuGTHMT2FC4cj38TAK@RJTXe0atua4aWpgwUC2BmUjoE4uudr0JmA2TKIxc6daXVmF7g8q5Nno3Jv8P9SIQ3SJK7haUgN/9SN6uAM4U4Qs56K7A8Fl9ywKyM@z95xjovdpgtjQRzyQ4qtsCE@nO0y2m1HsgqQbnkQBnUjMVa3OEzpFMT5HXqheK2tra8qu0lLKaO2h1aDWHrVKaO3xls5bBGdQi48o8xb1tvkIetdVpu3ZzBOtS6qdUNb6xYtVu727W@uW7baV36t01xBMEDsArdMN8yhas0lNTZNbYzBqnPcF96fQzStkfOyVR4G4j/xwsW@Q5rg6kixkUbvpSuVFT1Wkqu/MANIz4qvVSYS8PBUf8NoLLyIyUTOYtc4qhrV5Ywpsde6O7HvpkF9ugN4h624PH50G531@WQGwm2cBSCloi0Ry4Z6MEpEoguGPOVgQhZEgBfLyQtt8w28Ggscqem766BvEPHWx5AeuvlMzz73QPHf790G@ePr0JYfpn5979wFBKET37L4CLBmdr5IZUrPhnRjObkj9dJRkvt4zM7q7//1vPUj/rm6G9lWKZP5i3jiD0EhPev9eVeVD6YFfVqv188jHRu87czg2JfC2P2@snmuXvXFh@1BryPd3oNT34U4gMri5u8aNdeGPeu7svnpSLsObqYAYHXqBDsveMipcgXik9IY7n3tmuZXPiGlo35P4kd0zxU7UcxcaFbJ3J/YgCq/MpcBmJOc/QOos5WCLrWc2HGUjcaX95vd058X099CCzCErmwdPrcP8dg88iNi6z3bFsiFPrb/w7QvznJpnfTRXsyqYSbwBNrez@31g709i23HNcUq3lWbzGomibyfs5Ne3J8cP2g@fEBlk4ovryulehg5Ca5h9fyZw6fPLHzE8bgeO7cP6asL2qOKjL4nJuyVY3z6/oog2/OM2RFgHpRLTo8U@bFFQiuP7BzkO0@F7ms7OzurRovbEJ3AibJnd7wUjRBQvAN/V3lLzXuPwIn2x7UuFRVEasMoJ2Zc20gLfTmEjWS5m9xJq4ZeHbJZChUPGs2g9ZLG3iJptve/bvS1Gxp4TIajHXN/04ONhBZqQ0r3bqdFiGqop8stiKD3lhvsc2Q9F4G8PWm7kZLRpusd2fsAtif0K7QiX7MKI7hOaE43p797IP4wuXXFdHY6@rKTqB9yO7nOTQM59d3jP@Z61vvdSOB1cVrvDi5VUZY6/8j35qCjBhjVlVaPyoHpWGvOJ8dJ4ZRwZJ@zE86P0QXlgu56m4rralBeg54lnh7pDNrzcXj1sJWE8tLEDfr1HwbY/iPyt7YFp47JSNiejpE@@/SGxPOyjLOu7PmqezUShld/vozi5wO9KSrE9CeC8aXf33eBwvwfLc34C5Wn/G17andda0nJekcY7L8krkOm8yF9AfEpcXnmZ7SVZgepBowDuK4sSg3E4VbVLJU2TxCBaCIMQYDMoXmilWpeo4aYMHinjsNivtNuseD3ZrexaU9Zk8q7Mul0xK6@6HE5iXiF9I4a2i3a3WVR0XSkqnXCXVRQO6mKzvRrUvgHX9/hN0LlgnYV2wMtr1J5xWhc1PLgLKtwO7bCHfO1t6PFtshMlohIlyp08N/7H33t5PXvggsnAS20fgqATmChwh9F4T@DNsR/EsU31cJoDGYIvNtL6swOWjr3MGYoyNrzZ2xen23kNMj8NwsMxJWpLVAilogs7wMzOhNIENb3IFQaUI56PmjGFEDEKQjb2etkwNbDuQ8flNc5Z3Q2UJAQWZklEBlhmL1nPpdSF1wE@j6BbP4ouePmBKPnH30XlFZ0emRC1Z@j5UcASRgYXYfFyp@NEI1A9m@SLm0Q5iEpCRqAbQSJXMH9XvNeYM7R5SRiWqM8KooRGFEWfHZww/ZApdJBF9dG611eLB29@fteudJvfWGBiG2NSSYbLTf5Jf2KlcpnNQOpTsqvl7gq6F70Kk4sTOWeLDk34GcHcqMRqYiq1ubpmBc6An7dwu3PHvMDJq9ghxXE6yAhTrA88anxqsWiaRRX7n8DLmH6SsU067XMhErTECQ2j8zMq1tGQ4oR9ZUOyFd1h1mYFT0IgPtWHg@Zi17m87Tefu@cjnh5fVo1qrcnZKZ41Gy3eStxeRCcI7Y@dcddMZ1LpdCY/VaoTiC1KAP7YpJVz@Ovz66LRqnz9mtpXTJanSp1XZWh5F6@PXx4fnpwenL49gRingsvCiygJ7IWLICOIfbjqYeTzIxnII/Hc9PtuY@46pEePAKiqrGizBrMqDB7q0SPelctU1uWiaKKD@5B5x3JP33tEk@UehOVujh1zTedKVdJlF1eeKZ8Eh/U4gk@dEQ6juV7hqjgrMmuCGR3M3GKFLX1uM3Wzl8MLYbM9egGJ55wsg3Ful8BWQxG3AjqnXMAIMleyMf3foj1GGPkB2gnse7QDWvoe/iXULw5evrqLeQkpAdzpz0MLbovT78MJojI8YJ/bNp2xzKwmys/IZi4BHn8oCreI93Onls5rsGRHfXLJPlY1LQe@RU1pWTPyIAY78FO40F4PPuH8KiOXAl8qyq7z2qtcAOvGPMKVmSwRbNq8e1YClzFGyuN8EoOLHI7PnK46buy45j//@jdxxNjJ0P73vN1H@z9F@6NJArp7JiVonIuGxPLu5TFLEacE44E9WeKJQgWFIi8cIY8LIMFLLhACF8Qu@F3Mo7bfQZ5QAoRJPo/cHMfnJl11mGXxrmlSZEcC2Td44cqdQA/wkoYTBeZvIzrxhWc2tza3NiwTROqXswn5QcKAqihiQk3bhf1Il17c/HTusEajweQU23C3uVUXgjSL9sea/GlOaBGwkkgC2gxjMGQxAn2tfJhatEuWRkNpBSqWwrp1xHehF4QIlTcAotHrMJeHjBgU5aKiMwl3knF3ejVLbpBZhBELSE783H82kY6JxNyaLN2xXdCLHl4q8W5klcayGuT3BMYLK7vyKtNhsJD/WmE5Idr/IdrtTkX/1l11Zj23nYO7R9Pq7YNl4oXtn4QRVc9egFamVs1qzbS2tKV1IudTgVpaFV8xJdYB1pXjep@jOD14dvjyl6PjkztHqxxSuQ2mMKXVKHV0o9zuzhvKLZufifTpC/Pk9dMXM0EuU5V33aZq1eS3CbsH2XtRlrqLinfcQWRVfnTixTZ5JSOLTfQS4DOxf76DVdWup@1uo9UJC3fQf131vYeCsU5fdUCrk/JvPShshYOZF95OowuYxwMHunpGEN6X5aNdLx9N56bVltlzL0066JMMc9aD6Kg2blCricNnIYMZeviJ/E3RkoF3gcuR7hRDlgkRG9JoTsmNkTRjfcbzkdjT8e9u2CHS@cRzBHTKnavY@fEvGiD3f5kttgvYgmBBeXxXdMV3AFjm8@JCz@N1Jzu5yjmY95y4gaefzuihRb84TYMTipIMG4906HvndbvZnrD5YdNDB21GGvteptIJ18SgnRW4UTViwGr4Lh2QNXa6@Wkcmx2alfi52/EI8jqOYrbYzT53Z6032NCw5yNMDgtw2S@jAHB9fnvjkod32a@RjsGQozIjog0sas6DEfQ2gd0YupOeN0CUULUyHMpPlrU4sbO1EnahCnyoENXPVDFZFswfOmVckpjdtg0v7LkTVRkr2m6XpIP3yvj9paLJ0m0b4Eed@bln7/aZ52zt21m@CBfnhUsLZ5awAHl@3IAgQt9EozNmbBE82PT@n90whMmoIDuAgTB7BD4TrTz7KmR5/uWVJb/wL/npxe0ocahc@xFiYdGs881IfYqA8KnDOlmn3wkpKtSvzD@Zhlm/Vot@88pEINdaanHYtEq19VKpGK6rxZBC2ePHtIeZFhEpzwzZkCcA0ou@Voc8EVmbxbBetBtqsdesrvMReCyVtGsM@JaaxnXRnprFxwhMZbxJhHWoxVQjdVQMw5qCPtJQ0SwHdnytykye0HeACH3RK5WIBqN4RgR8MzsnJe6mOicm3zXV8wTJHAQzM75hDL//XrC2kKer06i0V62t7Wu6Kpvmeuf5ZV1p2/2q8Vv3@OL4@C9K4dmRJlsbcj3ckArmeuXrE9P89OkTcgbG2rpy2W2vqa0nT9bL9a3t9fJ@XbHK@1bl0SPL0tRqVTt59Ei12LGibNaUk4/Kb1Kh9QjKrW2t7T/6JBWkwlmrhI/Br6XS7u6@Tp@JbpT2pMKnBmAa3emUlRrthtFq6d1WWypcS4XJlAY3J403fFz7eT5BaXNn8gq3ht5tx8evDg9ODsvVhl6oPj8qV0/ePi1YeNicP1FXDU9vDg@eH709LVfFkJ9fvjt8e/zi4JnneXHa66W9aNht7e@XDNC2cbR1tG@0uiBk8lOpVWpmWcY@nK3DaJ@3Jm9NvQH8r6TCGw6tdzTAfpUK7UJb3avuVSt@5bIysS6si9fR0eL36Agd3qTyOUoqw8rQ6lmWNam4bytXk8pVJYiOrB7uLn4qAZpepT@pDCphJbSsG/Pc/xscRa@PIkwVYVg2qWQ0a6WP@@Do6DUm6wPxZ/x4lUoF9E0ql/it@Bb/fDyrVDQJu7bu5lZc3fqtzX3A5k637U68rCuzstJpK916wUw7HVMYnVyF3VD3dHp29vzg9ODszCS1FQqTRrG0X9L38Wm2So38tlfotUhokKSkqNhaxR0FXt2u8/JPkc4x21a3VLy2d0dTchrr1rrG1/tmpV5fP2D5wwYe8uZ2ve6mtsOpqCuCLFV1EaFU2epMqn1Wlbnj38Gys2qNhrq1qbVaW5t43NrGqqhQ54b20Zp3VbUokZWJHCUKu56KH/V62lD5R6MfTaOXGhO3lnatNgADII0/igEAG79//57@3o8vx6LFG@Ld@3nn8gNv4HN5z9i7DWzpECKZUpgWyIeGbGNTQ0buahtb6nZpJ/9prmmgXq4pNVAvK9JMYU2rQMxKBaP@Rraq6IH66lRWinzX8JH21nYkGR@pee4OvFBqtK7DnoQYcY64P2ZPKsgBfDrljPr9Ncn2RBfiHTYK2CWnru/TjovSvXGU@L0xUhCCw@Y3YXbGb/IWCEhTF5/g2HZHrjsejcbu/PPMS3ftz5/tGNmaWTcovFSrO9ub2zu16nZ5e2d7Y9Pa2twsW9Wy9WT7yU6lbFWsbWtre3PHKm9v7NQ2NjZ20Lu588Rclwo9t091tNE2k2vbnYo8fxOzFFlI1FdiRbf2Rtvy1hN5V649AQRyJzrMb9DXHiJj2JLoCyxMhQnQQoEpa/WpuY7EhzF1D581/PBffOaPdF3jb/LXHOTuZ02TRGVwy5IKU6lHZ3IbO3XyjNNGSyoqhFypSQW9Fm1EhWKxCDd62pJr8pGRSk0XCoLGCjINLqSTr9Gm9S38pV7YjZXahlLrNAtioVhPtEKr@sRI7atCV7xj6gZedgt8eVWtApt4/1e/Ucr6Y/6ZG/@dpbDUWvE8vgzAH2Pbf@oNBl71T5@@IodnisKqm4xZW2Qt3/SG@G3g8pdnR4JxeWtT1grpx7OPZ1VY0s4OSy52sZFPaDfBQZBsb@3I7DFLqYv@seDrVuF3zP7AtgC986ym7yLgj4JVac1B4r22qQ4TzlMbNF6PkP/O7YyRoVHCCEu78U4Y3/Ir/n8GeCcRXWQYKjXgTJ0yLw6xde5Yuxq7npUVVeqlqpY2L4IlbjZKQlapi4IlTeHV501goZXBmgTAK1fwn6rXtOrMa9BkuCP5yTHQZzai1KQmJd2cCq@r1aXl@h6npIXRS7QsjS@VBPhUkCX4cYKeYFv0zR9BXkCnII6aj9ZuAbQrXcAonYqSs/kjbCC7VeczlNkfZuPWeOR52ownTsKiM3@/UMVUWs/KQV0ittfjuvRn1dGuKf@sfwseP3Y@xu2gW9eCZkb3UimoT6UL1RMg61kzaOpWPQax9axdKnndZqD9WY058UGzAmDgpplT7Xqu6bCZqyvVyl/aof4t7JZftMOS1S2Pyusfml/KdrNSnuAPYiv75d8gvJko1az5pRTW7Qb@KBW@IYm4mZbs@s2iK4ZcqH7zS9vuNita3cfAUukFmAGdadsvlboakPvovDuw7j9@bJf81qTu67pGUB9rey/aGRrdUpOed1W7Mdn70h5h/K6KexNofA3EY9xNHWA@0FeHjIX6FqQLGidE3gTkBc3m@oe99Q/rzbW1L@2JHnTLQvy7lYXiifgJEb9sI@r6h2XD4iLhpyKq/JO3@5OxnjK5DOuDkMvx0khB4foH9MSL1TD9Hw)

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident tested to output 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ and Moorhens were [tested by WheatWizard.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37922205#37922205)
- Surface can be tested to output 66 [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).
- What was [tested locally](//github.com/gimmetehcodez/what)? (*ba dum crash*). What can now be tested using the driver?
- Japs was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).

## Explanation

### What

What is a Brainf***-based language that uses three-character combinations of exclamations and question marks. It reads 3 characters at a time, checking if they're a combination it cares about and throwing it away otherwise. The code to print 71 in Brainf***:

```
-[++>+[+<]>]>-.------.
```

Running this through the handy BF-To-What converter yields:

```
????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
```

Luckily, there are no other three-character combinations of `?` or `!` in the code.

I put this on the main C line to get it ignored by everything else and spaced properly:

```
main ( ){puts( p);}/*   (????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!)
```

### Underload

Underload doesn't like unbalanced `!`'s. I added parenthesis around the *what* code to make Underload ignore it.

### Incident

I somehow tokenized `ar`. I added a useless `ar` before the *what* code to detokenize it.

### Prelude

Prelude didn't like where the parenthesis were, since there were other unmatched parenthesis in the same column. To fix, I added an extra three spaces before my code so that Prelude wouldn't bork and *what* would like it.

Comment: `ar` was my fault with my attempted rushed evil fix; `are` instead of `fir` fixes that, but requires an extra `<space>a` somewhere, so I replaced one of the Prelude-padding spaces from the last line with an `a` for a free fix. All those changes are reflected in my answer now if you want to use them to shorten this answer a bit.

Comment: @SnoringFrog It's not a problem. Prelude and *What* wanted an extra three characters before the *What* code anyway, so it's fine.

Comment: Can you please edit #38 C into C99

Answer (score 8):

## 76. Trefunge-98, 2056 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111\4O6O@x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;'␉;print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}() )wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":"75"
#include<stdio.h> 
main (  )  {puts(p);u8;}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72" )';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@<>
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"# xi xi xi xi \++++>/ xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004683 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2137 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTtNd9pKluvozD/oTUXwIgnQFxh/IMB2ErvHr5O2J3aSOQHiCFGAYn1FEgbHIWe2M2cWve/NLPt/9HZ@Rf@RN/dWSYANdvLOzGKIkUqqW3U/695bt0jfTsa//VbADzkLvZuRF6YkpUlKBrF7TWONPL8hB7ab1Ks1QWBQcTiYOG4wIumYEjeIJikZuh5NBMdOSZtE2SwaNkiBxNQecDBhGMYEhxD/yiMucaKI9D17rDnEcwH22NgF@CT0ESalcRRTuCYkoHRAkog67tB1GC5CZykNEjcMEo24zhWZup5HBtSDAUsCnApMRibJyiuOThMGoUDg40T3yF08FSnABDRnmUZ2zFgOScT4zzmfxnYUAZFCgZwD4anr04S4qZQQaicuyhGGJDQYMGlFCwmHxA5WuSTXrk1soHcSs7kTGqfAnsbmJWMaU5jSRuSj2PaJPI3dFESAwjwkZ9SOyUVMqQJYQAk0cewI6LiDEpCFiCFFRjSmrGZTOjo9lkBpfIRmR6lQiGsX//KrYBOtRYqXFnxbomgJR39@SW6LXWwDFTAZKDaKZVshre8k0btdCt@Z2ddH8VyAWQWQikf0MEp1mNmOUyBv2VKvq1rkraAlzXuaWDEkDjUAXZCTgLyrML6cSRxToGIpUvsKWPbCYATSBFbjSYDSCMi2AQpwwmCQVAi9BpmFAddQOGXyvRi7oLIEFWL3QTy2g5Lni4CJE5YBWF4mzxxvEnoTBgcjkxTND2QCQ3HGkyF5R4a26@EQ6MepONUxTSZeimMmwQD17rsBHWgkJ8MJBwjkh9eAzoZJ2QtYN/7KamNEATCoIWSsYtc//vLXwWgE8xw6ThgPMmN9RwahM/GBYJsRa4MhormGge0xsgCugtj5cEBwbXvuwE4RfXCToWBEMKzTcOINSAgI46kLC2tsX8NiHA6pk1Ju4uEkBRorxLevuI9wud0C477dB8UyBAw3Y1slBy9ASw7lBqP6k3S4S9ToiEiJ/lHeb8j7T7sUaFM0pVTU9ZEF1qaV2Ct4kh4znHeHS32i9Vy4Ia4iLxpPwGdAT5BE4E1iFKZjAzsJOpUU/F6F9JmgmScCQ2dLdEqlmJI@rOucMWYj3AZwvIrrNpthqdMc7q6J0cGKhYF1gpGlyZqT8MIpIGa0ofMEmw4QuT2yAVWaMXTIGeIY2Zu7rF0FYOk4W5@SXbXvgnbQDsDVZMpY4RHAa1UOA7Nx7a0sCt@@gVkc7qKXmiTuEJTsg93GN8ShuBhgVVDu5xDJhBlG4oIdhUNiqNV6/QfKT2P9UP2g2@pX/VEdI/P31HxIhnRKPDsYTewRGHIYwBDbcWiUZisIOElSWCP33SB7qWY@XUvGQvHgPm7m2zJvv4IDvQ/XXuahbTR7EJQPolY9WOXEjkdsJZKBG8N68W7uYweA63vIxU8IcoeAT@IDJOSBCYyMzqgzSWG5gSFPx64zBttF6gK@YLl3vI8eXq1iB5ejDheokRiz/awqaPriFZLx4BQqanR9HvD6OFX7zgum/NUXj89sJ/6GicMFieChVt5quq2B7WVCg2h@jpkEuL88dLOVtUgvFvIEAf@KgSmmXyagMLBndxQgiB0swv6KZ3STQIJQ4SYuSB0DONr6xckpxoP3lOcwIHcey1adeQgZDQzPAjR25EoQqDMOiRoQKaNBFlk8/Qxk6UnssIa6kkSIigZyklFerCuf6DPPze4HVNJeh2MopQrpiGKvAjHMS8CEgonnwcMkYEtMpsot2JpDk0SDBQOy1TAbAerEMlXmdwHTcRxOCZ0rlrQJ3e9UyItJ3539P9SIg3TxK3C1ogb26mf0sAaYK0IUM9GtQTDZvQh99PPkPeMY6X0eQ2wYQjwQopt0DJ5OdYhot8KIAkl3PIkEdEJyLisWS@gkSfscuoF8Kz19@lRqSG2pAq19aDWxtY@tMrT2WUtlLYTTsMVGVFgLeztsBL7rSfNOPvNM6aFqZ5i1fnUj2e40GrVexe6Y2b2KdwWCCcQOgFbxBvNISquFTUUR21NgVOsPBc7@BSjnFaR85JWLkXgICeJy4yAskHUFkQujdteXisueKs9V3@k@iE@LbjZnEeLqVGzAaze4CtFGdT9vXRqaWb8zBex31kcO3WTMLndA18ha72GjE78/ZJcNAI0sDYCcAvdIKBfmyjATCUOw/CkD88Mg5KSAvNzA1t@wmwbRYxM9d530HWKeU1jzI6ru1fS@G@h9OnwI8vj58xMGM@z33YeAQChId37fABZP@ptkBrnZeC2IkztSv5jEqacO9BTv9L//bQDSX9fN2L5JIJu/WjQuQWioJ3X4oKqyofjALpvV@nniwU7vB3M4NmbwtrdobJ6rQd5QsH1Qa8A2eECp54E/AZGBn1s3blgX3mRA8/vmSZkM7@YCfHTg@ipY9rZmMAXCI@Y3zPs8MMu9hIZPgxuf2Avtgc63oi5dapTLns7sURjc6CuRTYv7P0FqnnOQ5d4zHU/SCb/ihvNHunMj/D62IDNIo3743DzKbg/AAxHbD9kuXzboqtVjz77S@9i8HEJzM6ucmdgdwe42vz8E9v48sh2qTxO8Peg/gkkSMUWy1kNgkD3GHr8@BOIGDkTWYNl4CBBY9Njl91gdMwLH9sD0atzwsN6jrsjIvSdVz@7fYDwb/34DQqyjcpmo4ENaTrls1IgaLjdky8pSFD083nGy8Xt7m0fzIhSbwAlh70x/FJQgsrg@iKA6WGk@aCRuqC73fwm3LMwHNjkj@9qG/MCzE7CVNJM4vQYNsctjtoshw5l4drxsPWa594jK9@APbeOWIyPXCSG4c1PFB8/daK0B5n33c6TlNFhgZJflUHzK3OhLSIMwEn9/1JeGToq7pwfM6CfcE9@44NZwxS608CGhOeEUvw@u4HF4Tfl1c1j6upGqn3A/qsdMApLv9eED50fW@t5NwPnAZbNbvNpIVep4G983yOswjGHnmpCqZjyqno3GfK6daK@0U@2cnLtemDwqD9i3Jwm/bjblJWg/du1AddCGV9ubh20kjIU4csiuDyjY9kaht7070m24PGgFk3iI3j67/6yTWzgp0/yhk1qkNWFgZvcHXfwV/P3IQLAqAj7dxfxm0dxsLD/waNlm4GE2YQeAIzezeGzsLmwsTuhG4wLcGcxh7Iyn9s2jJvijePKQsPN40sAqPkulHyOG7XzesPL2ot6UVLKqPLxz46wKmywOOgongRNTVn3K99OkgDWxiQ@eOw1jjTA4WbbLZUUR@CD0AaMAwHIoVmzGeh@vYycEnHHKYGHP1umQ4u2sYTTMOWkRsSGSXo/PyipPR7OIVYnf8KGdot1rFSVVlYpSN2gQQ2Kg1ANFbAS178ANXXbjdC5ZJ4HtsxIjtnNOLV7HBE@JxeuxHQwgZX0buKxU4IQxr8bxki/bHvz9b4Ospj@iwKTvJrYHgsBTqNCn43C6z/Fm2A@jyMYzAZwDMiWPFxPUF4ckmbqpM@alfHDkb48vdrM6bHYqBg9nmKuuUMGVCl2wC07tlCuNUzMIKbeKDPFiVM4URMeJH5CpO0jHiQYuL3Aoq/PmtUegJEawII1DtKoKOSEDimkbq4V8noBuvTC8YiUYpOTvf@PVZ@h00YSwnaNnxyErGAl4R5OVfB0nnADV@SRfaRxmIDIKGWL8BCRyAzZN@XuFOGOblcXBEtW8KIxoeGH4xeE5UY@IhId5WCO23KFcPHzzx3cdo9f6TnwddnI6lqWY3MRf1B0zESskB7HmaFer3QZ0L3slIhZnYsYWHhyxc5KFUfHVRGRsM3XlRV6fnTkxu6NTVuRllfwAUxg8zAkSWB/wqLCp@aJpFWXYAvpuStTzlNTxxJOCSKDFT6kIniFiwRKHFGfkGxmjragOMesGPHGBeFgj91vLjfdq5UN/SfsTtkO4rmrVWouxU7xsNdusFdNBiKconY/daU9Pcql0u7NfjOoMxBbGAP5Mx5Vz9OeXt0WtbXz7loDvE8W5ZLHKFC7v4u3ZydnR@cXhxdtzEOOcc1k4DmPfXroINILIg9A0Dj12LAXyiF2a/NhtPGF@Q3iSAcoyKdqkSUyDgId6snAsmVhFVSzyJu9jnmTRd68zcx9Dl2SujpwxbWeKlZJVN1fJDQCFB2tyAn41Jx4M53aDu2LsiKQFDKnAEANfELx42sTY3V4GzwW@j88g9IyNVSjG6hJqMxDyyoEzujkMJ3IjE/P/I8ojiCM/phyhfkQ5AAs/wr6C@Pjw5NXbN0fruFfQZjBrIAsLWfkdwNEMkgnwg0Nm4XjalNtNmJ0W5o4B/P6Yl7Btb@nakkU1Gi1piI7Zg7WNi4Lt1RNc3AT9iEYOvQQc6WAAnqF/k6JjAY/KC9CLKrRYAAFoizhXIaKAsElr/dQIHMcUUj7nEx9cZHBs5mTTwWuX6v/4y1/5YWs3hfa/Z@0htP@Ttz/qKKD10zlO40I0KJZ3J2ckgWjFGfft2QpPGDAwILnBBLIeHyR4zQSC4JzYJb/LeeTOO5AnKAGEiZ4PnR3DR@OePE7TqKHrGN8hgx5qrIJHZ6AH8JUa5Jz6lwmefYN/1rfr21umDkSq1/mE7EhlhOUkPqGiNMCEhGs3an3qO6TZbBIxcWyPtrYtLki9aH@siZ8WhBYBVuCpQIfAGBiyHAF97WyYXLTLpoJDcRVKpkR6FkR5rhcIFDJrAIiCr4NMHiJEojATFZ7O0FnKnOpNnuJAfhGExEc5sV9A5BOpMBGfWxGFNdsFeqGH1YzcO7mltqoG8T2CsQpTQ9xkOgQs5L82WE4A7f/g7U7XUL/3Np3eL2zncP2QXr5/xI68kIPzIMQy4jHQSuSqXq3p5raysk7EbCqgFlfFN5gS1gGsK4e6n8MoOXxxdPLr6dn52iEzg5Tug0lEajfLXVWrdHqLhnTP5nORPj/Wz18/P84FuUpV1nWfqk2T3yfsAWTveZFuHRXrWENkGj878bJOsJGRZRVhBfAFLyCsYZWV23mn12x3g8Ia@m@bfgFS0Er4ow9odRP2@w@JbHAwJ3np8SK8AvN45GhbTRHC/bp6yJ0XLvEEudrWB/RaxyNPQVuWNMWi3LxDrcKP4bkMcvTgJ7I3RVMEvEtcjrBWDVolhG/IwwUld0YuhI08n/KdHfsVix1AUh@7DodOmHPl@z/2kwvYAZyky00DbERgQblsb3TD9gGwzBfVlYHLCm92fJNxsOg5p76rXuT04KJfniuCE4IdNmw/krHn9i271ZmRxanbY0eOWhJ5birjWd9Mw/0VcCMryIDZ9CgeFTb3etm5JMmPD8vsBPJsAvI6CyOy3NO@pHnrDWxryMsJTA4WQMmvEx/ghuz2hqKHp@TPoQqDQY5STkQHsMgZD5o/qAN2bUxnA3cEUUJWKuBQfjHN5dmlrZRhLyqBD@Wi@iOWjFYF87vOW1ckZndszQ0GdCZLU0lp9FA68F6avr@WFHHNBtihb3YCPLh/@puvfTvNFuHi5HR14eQJCyDPzl0giOBv8vC0HTYKLtj0wZ9oEIDJyEC2DwZC7AnwGSuV/IehlcXPeFb8wj9nxzj3o8SRdOuFEAuLusW2JNYcAsKnLumm3WE3wKhg3eh/0DXdupWLXutGh0CutOXiuGWWa6VyuRiU5GKAoezZM9zJzIsQKS81URNnAKQWPcUCeUJkbRUDq2g35eKgVS2xEfBYLiu3MOB7omu3RXuuF59BYKrAm5hbh1xMFFSHoWnmHOhDDRX1im9Ht7JIxBn@GgrRF91yGWnQipdIwHe9e15mbqp7rrO9k5UlSPrIz834jjH89lvB3IZcfS6H5f1q7emBSkS91H15bUkde1jVvvTOrs7O/lXpylLhxalobolWSRcKesn4tqPrnz59gpyBKB1V6nXk9s5Oyaps75YqBxVTqlgF4pmGaSpytap0t4Jz8sR68uSJbJ5JUr0mnX/EI/z9p/CP/cFn8YjXp@xN9pqBrH@eKkT@MhMK7SdgJ7XtpwdPPgkFoXDZLsNHY9dyudE4UFV1Bl@tvC8UPjUBptmbz8vNTrOptduzttprd4TCrVCYzYVCVUQBlIRCa9Z8wybovMxmKn95BZem2utEZ6@ODs@PKtWmWqgeH76oVM/fPi@Y8FRfPmJnDR/fHB2@PH17UanyUX88eXf09gzeu64bJYNBMgjHvfbBQVkDGg@0dg@Imf1SbpdbaZqSD5clzY6Fwsv27K2uNoGAV0LhDYNVuwpAfxMKnUJH3q/uVw3PuDbMK/PqdXi6/Ds9hffuzPgcxsbYGJsD0zS7W6fbpwczg741boybmeGHp@YAmhT@GT40XWM4M0ZGYASmeWe2h//80/D1aQhThTAsnRkpzmoM4T46PX0Nkw0B/Wf45xoGUjkzruHP8Ez2@XhpKIYAO8JefTuqbn/pMN9S3@t16MxNeyKpSN2O1LMKetLt6tyYxSrYI3bP55eXLw8vDi8vddwizZrF8kFZPYBPq11uZrf9wqCNctOagiTDri3qShAqbItVlop4Stwxe@Xird2YzNETkZJZUpgXqRuWVTrM2lvQzpq7lkUT22EkWNITTpQsU4h7smh2Z9UhqYosnOzBYjZrzaa8XVfa7e06PG7vKqpsYOeW8tFcdFWVMBalmRjGErmd83/y7bwps4@C/xQFX2bXtnIrNwEEYOoKe@YDZIUo0/fv3@P3/fR6yluswd@9X3SuPrAGfK4fGLvegJ0iRF4iFeYFdM0B2aorkOhTZWtb3i3vZf9aTxUgX6xJNSBflApCrrCWWUB2hYJmvRHNqiihAi0sWoUe1TxIp2t7gggfodWnIzcQmu1bASJPH7KJKdkxILPwPDsm4XD4VLBd3gVRFLYfsANPqOfhPg6TyGkYe4MpJDYIB1vqmNj4fwZgbSUJhY9/ZtMJpdPJZEoXnxdu0rA/f7YjdHsQCA1Bw6BVre7t1nf3atXdyu7e7lbd3K7XK2a1Yu7s7uwZFfB7u@b2bn3PrOxu7dW2trb2oLe@tyMUaDBwh7oODsYURcIaAzrEot1kl4i13a4hLt5EJIFkJxxKkaSa@5NdcXtHbJTgLu6LNWiKO3UAhmwNf0fRxF@chNq4TQT88RCRwTETcovLSI4Ua7JrzQFbzsWCDgILQtMIfFVVwH4eJmRxpyoSRbIAzuJj/mllUHzVgO1sjDk1g4eUc3tPxNcA0mzX@6VGxVQrB802n49sm0JhLgzw1HRrz0JvO4e@ooSkSjWhoNbCrbBQLBbBOV@0xZp4qjX1zO22deZ2u@iG0e9pQguwoFEUxAKZucu/Lge/8@5//xcmSHsh@RbWze/Br1ahEUm1LanWbRX4ijd3lEK7uqMl9k2hx98ReWtHIfDEPEXVLAyn7LNYZ2urbqW14Xl67bMoBGTs/mEwGrnVP7z@9A12IpIE4d3c/q42@V8TLi9OOV3idl1UwLqT5OPlx0uIjHUiVusiIWWdwH5G/9cq2PHe3vbudkH4Tdcf28lA7yIRG1LIUSb@pkzsMHZf21g6ChbZGDReTyBlXxgqQUvFHHfcvvuOWe@dV@w/icA7AelCU5GxAa7aqbB6Fikxt91TyG1eC5WxF8txyqJ6F9N0EgfEsHiVFadwrUUTsOAqIy0EYMU2cM6y2zIt4jZxMrhDvpZhwE8@otzCJu4TGBVuT7GE1bIko6QNo1doWRlfLnPwOSeL8@P4A84271s8Ank@Ht84cjZauQfQMXoAI3UNKWPzZ9iAhFxezFAhv5uNe@MhNVVynhgJy87s/VIVc6GUVnxLQLZLkSX8SXaUW0yZre/@s2fOx6jj9yzFb6V4L5d9ay5cyS4HKaUtv6WaVgTEWmmnXHZ7LV/5kxwx4v2WAcCAG2dOlNuFpoNWpq5EqXztBOr3oFc57gRls1eZVEofWl8rdsuozOALYqt4lS8gvFyUctr6Wg4suwlfzN7vSCJqJWXbulsthiFXstf62rF7LUOxPBhYLh8DM0Bn0vHK5Z4CyD3oXB9oec@e2WWvPbM8VVUQ6mNt/7iTQqNXbuFzQ7abs/2vnQmMb8hwbwEaTwHiYdxdHcB8QJ8FMubqW5LOaZwheTMgz2@1Sh/2Sx9KradPv3Zmqt@rcPE3jKXikfgZEr9qI3Lpw6phMZGw4xxZ/MVt/KKVEiJWwPpAyJVoZSSnsPQBeqLlapj/Dw)

Languages that are not on Tio:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use python 2. Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse (#73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway (#74) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98 (#76) [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Note that flags must be `-v 98 -d -3` for Trefuge. Could also be installed via pip.

Languages that use abstracted interpreters in the test driver:

- V (#2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)
- Alphuck (#44) [local](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master)
- What (#71) [local](https://github.com/gimmetehcodez/what/blob/master/what.c)

Other languages:

- Japt (#7) was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Surface (#66) [local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip). Tio Surface interpreter is no contest because it was created after challenge was started.

### Explanation

#### Funges

The Funge-98 specification defines Befunge-98. But less talked about is that it also specifies two other languages, Trefunge and Unefunge. They are nearly identical besides number of dimensions. Trefunge is the 3 dimensional part of this family of languages, with formfeed as the character that separates layers in the third dimension.

When running the polyglot from the previous step under Trefunge it follow the same path as Befunge-98. So we needed to separate Trefunge. This happens on the second line. The relevent part of the second line was previously

`>77*,;68*,@;'1,@`

but is now

`>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l`

For Befunge-93 nothing important has changed since ; is a nop.
For Befunge-98 and Trefunge we no longer print the 1 before the semicolon delimited jump. this semicolon jump now jumps over the output both the Befunge-93 output code and the Befunge-98 only code. after the jump the next command is #, which jumps over the space. The l following this jump is where the paths of Trefunge and Befunge-98 diverge, being a command that sets the IP downward in 3d space in Trefunge  and acts as a reflector (like unimplemented commands should) in Befunge-98.
After Befunge-98 reflects the # now acts to jump the semicolon where it now prints its answer in the same way as before, but travelling leftward rather than rightward (and now sharing the @ with befunge-93).

The rest of the code  relevant to Trefunge is near the rk-lang code.

```
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@<>
```

The formfeed is what separates everything after it to being on a different level in the 3rd dimension (just like newlines separate rows in the second dimension).
After being sent downward by the l in the second line the IP turns eastward at the first >. The 5b* puts 5 on the stack then 11 (b in hexadecimal) then multuplies to give 55, the ascii code of 7. The : duplicates the stack. The comma pops the stack to print out the 7. The 1- subtracts 1 to give 54 (ascii for 6) before that is printed out by the second comma. the @ ends the program.

A < was added to match the > because several languages disliked the mismatched >.

#### <><

The increase of the Befunge code's length by 3 misaligned the <>< code on line 1 from the <>< code on line 2. So the fish code was moved left by 3 characters, not breaking anything in the process.

#### Cubix/INTERCAL

The DOs in the INTERCAL where changed to being FACs again so that the cubix IP didn't start on a D. Standard alterations made to move the Cubix capsule.

#### Incident

<> had become a token so another <> was added to the end of the Trefunge code. '; had also become a token somehow. I first tried to fix this by putiing a space in the middle of the tokens occurrence on the scripting language line. This caused '<space> to become a token, so I used a tab instead of a space.

#### Golfing

Golfed 6 spaces from the last line, decided to line up the prelude brackets properly this time rather than guessing.

Answer (score 8):

## 80. [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 201, 2221 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}((x{}5){})>)}{}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
<3>
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004337 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2304 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17
**80** in Klein 201

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLc9tIkj4bsf9gLmWQbQAk8SJFvfiQZFuadXd7pLVke6JJWoZAUIQFAmwAFCnLdOx1N/Yw97nscf7HXPdXzB/p/bIKfEikZHfEbMRCJlCoyqrKV2VmZcEXTtL/7bccXewkCm4ugyhlqZekrBv7115ssOc3bN/xk2q5IkkcKo66I9cPL1na95gfDkcp6/mBl0iuk7ImG2ajGFRgORZ7TleASb0oZtSFDa4C5jN3OGQXgdM3XBb4gD2ytgGfRAOCSb14GHu4Jyz0vC5Lhp7r93yXz8W8SeqFiR@FicF894qN/SBgXS9AhwUCbgmDsVGyVCWmM6RuJDFc7vAeuvO3vAeY0JuR7A2dmJMcsSGnf0b5OHaGQyAp5dgpEE/9gZcwP1US5jmJT3xEl8QLu5xbwzmHI@aEy1Sya99hDvAdxXzsxItTkGfwcVnfiz0M6dDkl7EzYOo49lOwgJh5wE48J2ZnsedpmAVC8BLXGQKPO1NisohmSIkQgwurXlcOj48UCE30MJxhKuXiytm//Sg5zGiw/HkNv4Ys16TDP71kt/k2lYEFBoNgh7HqaKzxlSVmu@3hN7EvzMt4KmFUCVwJmBkNUxMjO3EK9BYl/bpsDIOlaVn9niSWFElAdSEL9ipk70qcLncUxx6wWLDUuQLJQRRegpsgNR6FxI2QbVoQgBuF3aTEvGvwLAqFhKIx5@9Z34fIEhKIcwH2OC5xXiwCzk4sA2hexs/ZvEkUjDgceiYpqR94gq404qsee8d6jh9QF7TTUALr2EtGQUp9RmGX5D7wQ69rsBkabtQloEF0jekcDMorsG4GS6uNIwVgiCHipFLTP/7y1@7lJcY5cN0o7mbK@o51I3c0AMIOR9aBIpK6RqETcLQAV6LZRXdMcO0EftdJafrwJpuCI8FnHUejoMsiTBiPfSysvnONxdjreW7qCRWPRilwLLGBcyVshC/0FoQPnAsIlk/A5@Zk62z/BaTkekJh9MEo7W0zfXjIlMT8oO7tqntP2x5w0wytkDfNyxq0zSjwKrwpjynOu4OFPEl7zvyIVlEw7I9gM9ASJkNYk5iY6TogJyGjksLuldgFZzS3RFB0vkTHnhJ77ALrekYY1xGhA9Rfp3WbjbCQ6Qzurop53SUNg3ZCydJkxUgE0RgTc9zIeEKnQ5rcuXQwVZoRdCAIEjPymrukXYXQdBrtwmPb@oUP6ZAewNRkwliiEeCVsoDBaEJ6S4ti4NxgFFeY6IUkmd@DkAfQ2/iGuR4tBqwKT9g5mmTEFSPxoUdRj1l6uVr9hvDT2DzQfzEd/bP5qIyJ@HtiPmA9b8wCJ7wcOZdQ5ChEF8d1vWGarSBQkqRYI/fNIK/UM5tuJH0pv39/bm7bMmu/NAdZHyG9zEI7pPZg1ACs1gOscubEl3wlsq4fY70EN/dnB8D1vcnljwRyB4GP8gMozBwTlMybeO4oxXKDIo/7vtuH7hJ2oViwwjrenx5Vy7PD5Oi9@dSEjN18VpYMc15FaDw4hE4SXR0HVp@Gat6p4MJfrnh8ZCcZrBk4mqMIC7VUa5iOAd3LmAZvfkqRBMzfzHXzlTUPL@b8BIN/JMcUe7@OIDDos38ZEogTzt3@kmX0k1CBq/ATH1wnB066fvbqmPzBe0/EMOC78GXLxjxCRIPumYOmhpkQJM/tR0wPmZLhoMrcn34CWmYSu7ygLwURsmaATyrxizfNBvokYrP7DpU1V@H4lEqJtWS5U4IPCxKoUDgKAryMQr7EVE@7ha65XpIYWDDgrUHRCLCTi542vQuY9uNozLypVlPWTfc7BfJidOFP/h9KxCW8xB1ULYmBV32PHFYAZ4KQ5Yx1KxCcdy@iAdl59p5TTPg@j@EbevAH0vAm7cPS6S6TnUY09IDSHUuiAE8E56pW4wGdohifIj9Ub5WnT58qu0pTKaG0h1KdSntUKqK0x0s6LxGcQSXeo8RL1NriPaiuo0xbs5EnWodEO6Go9bM/VJ3W7m6lU3JadvYs01ODM4HvALROD4yjaI0GFTVNbo5BqHHRkwT5ZxDOzwj52M8@eeIeAsTFxkGaT9aWZMGMyl1bKi9ayiJWfWcOwD5jeLM@ipCXh@IdXvvhVUQ6ag5mpXPLsKt3hsB@Z7Vnz0/6/HYHdAWt1RbeOxlc9PhtDcBuFgYgpqA9EvGFmzKKRKIImj/mYIMojAQq4JcfOuYb/jDgPdbhc9dI30HmuYc1f@npOxXzwg/NC6/3EOTR8@evOEzv4sJ/CAhMIbxnzzVg8ehiHc8Qm/VXnDi7w/WzUZwGetdM6en9z793wf1V2fSdmwTR/NW8cA6mkZz03oOiyrrSC7@tF@unUYCd3jfGcB2K4J1gXlg/1i5740H3IdaQb/CAaRDAnoBlsHOryo11EYy63uy5flDOw7uxgOgd@gMdmr1pWFyAeKX4hlufB0a5F9CIYWjjEweR0zXFVtT3FhIVvPcmzmUU3phLns2IL74D1VnMwRZ7z7Q/SkfiThvOb8nOH9LvsQWZQVrVg@f2YfZ4AB5IbD6ku2LZkKnWjwLnyryg4nkPxfWkCmJi/xK729nzIbD3p0PH9cxxQo8H7Uc4SoZckLz0EBiixzgQ94dA/NCFZw0XhYcAQWLAb79H67gSuE4A1asIxaN8j77EI/8eVwPn4ob8Wf/3KxDNelksMh02pOEWi1aF6dFiQ7bILA2HD/d33az/zs763iIJxQdwI@ydvW85JXgWfwAWlLtLxQeVxI/0xf4vEZpF8cA6Y@RcO4gPAieBrqQZx71rSIjfHtNdchnuKHDiRekxzb2H1GwP/tA2btFz6LsRnLtQVXoJ/LXaGlLcdz9GWgxDCUZ@W3Slt8yMvkQYRJ7466O2NHJT2j09oEbfYZ7ExoW2hkt6YUQPMc2NxvR7cAX3o2tP3Ne7pc9rsfoO86MHXCUQfK9277rf0tb3fgLjg9t6s3i1FqvUDdbW77LXURRj55qwsmE9Kp61ynxqvDJ@No6NU3bqB1HyKD@wb08ScV@vygvQi9h3Qt0lHV4ur@@2FjHu4tgBvz8gYCe4jILN7UvTwe1BLRjFPbL22fN7jdzcSNn2N43UPKyJQjt7Pmjir/DvWwpCWRHYdJ/im3lxvbJ8w6Jlm4GHycQOgHquJ/HI2p7rWJx4a5ULc2cwB7HbHzs3j6rgt/zJQ8ye@ZNdyuLzUPpRZL45zcbj03S/z16tDLv1@LB3hPxT4MFgX9F9RbSsbNnUg2/h3vA8/TxxlpSy4wXU@XGWTk7mJza5V6EbezyNNksMsBwl90YDuKA0ig3G4VTVKRY1TRKdyJhdhgCbQfGsOSUuRUI@YfAqKYfF5rPVYvnbya61a09Zg8m7Mut0xKg8hXY4GfJ09xvRtZV3Oo28outKXmmHu8xSOKgXQKPWgjp34Ho@fwg8F6Sz0BnwXCmVZ5TWREIWJp@y8H0n7CL2fhv6POfhRrFIK4rcNd/n/P1v3exw4tIDkQM/cQIwgo7TooHXj8Z7Yt5s9oPh0KHDDRoDIV8gsiL6iwOWjP3U7YszCXikt0dn21lCOTvew8sJBd1LWAihognb@dRJhdAENt3IE@qdTTzvNSMKbn40CNnY76b9xIDtDl2PJ6xnSVRgEhNYmMYRLY8Se8W6HsWfPKnzaQTZBlF0xXNJhMnf/ybS6Gj0SYWoPJuen@sszchg5m2eu3bdaASsZ4N89uIoA1GJyQhWRuDIDRanJ@o15vYdnt@HJuqz7DZNIzLcLw5OmX7IFDqVpGR3ze@p@YM3f3zXsjqNr2xgYktqUn6N803@Qd@yE7nEZiC1KenVcrOF5kWrwuT8RM7IohMwfuAzVyqxmphKZS6uWbZ6wA/PuN55Y56t5kcSIcVidCoVJlgfeNX40GLRNPIq9rIDP2X6acqqdHTrgSUoieM2RoehlHmlLvkJ@8L6pCu6y@yqhTfBkICS/YPGIoOwnMIxX3oXI77VuS4b5UqDk5M/b9SbvBR73YiOg1of2uOOmcy40m5PfrDKE7AtigH@zKSVc/inl7d5o2l9@ZLAiMvyVKnxFBst7/ztyauTw9Ozg7O3p2DjVFCZO4rigbMwEaQEwwA@th8F/HwN/Ih9L/m22XjC7Yb0JANUVZZ3WJ3ZFoOFejI3LBlbZV3Oi6Jo45Zk3navMTMfPZ9lpo6dcGlnglWSZTNXmikAMQ9rcgS7OkMeinO7xlxxcmTWAEE6COLgc4Tnb@sIu9vK4QXD9@gdTM/IWIbipC6g1gMRrQI4w1vACCTXEjH9J2E@hB/5NuYE9S3MASx9a/aliY8OXv389s3h6txL02YwKyBzDVn6oOFwgqgIdrDHNZyOzWZ6E2XHnjPDALvfF7l4J1iYtmSeVidN6pFhDrC2aVHwpENCi5uRHTHYQZDAkHa7sAwXNykZFlhUkUmfp9PlHBhgzP1cickSwSaN1eMvGI4xYlf3o@ic53B85GTdCXLbM//xl7@KU@N2ivJ/ZOUeyv8lyh9MYtDqMaPAcc4aYsu7VycsgbcShA@cyRJN5DDIIfnhCOHbABy85gwhcIHsgt7FOGrrHfgJIYCZZPnI2PH5vLij9tN0uGua5N@xFegZPBXpTSAH2EoDwbP564gO8WGfzc3q5oZtAkn9ejYgPxu6pLyYGFDTdqFC0rU/bHy8cFm9Xmdy4jqB19isCUaaeedDRf44RzQPWEmEAi2GPuiy6IG2ZtZNzTtFW6OutAoVW2GdGry8kAschcoLANGoOsz4IcMTRRmr6JjJm6TcqN7MQhzEF2HEBsQn/inHbCAdA4mxNVla0V3gixae/PLvxJbGshjk9wTGU2W78jrVYdCQ/16jOSHK/ynKrbalf@2s@wxhrjsHq18bqPe/FSBa2P5pGFE@9Ai4MrVsliumvaktrRM5GwrY0qr4giGxDrCuXM//FA2TgxeHr348PjldOS3nkMp9MIUpzXqxrRulVmdeUO7p/Iylz4/M09fPj2aMXMYqa7qP1brB7yP2wGTvRbZxdSresDKRbX3vwIuEx1pCFumQJcAXIhOyMquq3U5bnXqzHeZWpv@y7lOWnFGgr1dQaif8QxaFrTEwr2Y51LPoCurxyBm9nhKE/3n5tH6WgaWj8HLT7HrXJp3dSsYiNyvn1fodbDXxPYHgwWx62ImsJo@dWpMt5nKllbTWMiIisxDNMbnTc85sovlY7Oz45zhOiKA@9l0BnXDjKvZ//NsR7ABepYtNAzYiWFA@3xvd8H0Alvk8TdT1eQbRiW8yCuYtp97A189m@NCiXxyQwghFcYrtR9IP/Iua02hN2Pz48LGzUyMZBn6q0qHlxKD9FahRNSLArgcenXnWdzrZASubnYMW@VHqyQj8OomGbLGnfenNSm@wrWEvRxgcGuCxH0cDwPX4441HFt5jf4p0dAYflRkSLcyiZjQYg24Vsxt9b9L1L@ElVK0Eg/KDbS8OYR2tiL2oAhsqWPVHyn0tM@Z3HRwvccxpOYYfdr2JqowVbbdD3EG9Mn5/rWjyig7w0@vsKLt7/xh7tvadNFuE8yPg5YUzC1gweXaABCdCHxfSZwPYKPjQ6f2fvDCEyqhAewAFYc4IdMZaafaFa2n@PdKSXfjX7Dzqvpc4VG6DCL4wb9b4lqQ2hUP42GbttN1rh@QVajfmH0zDrN2q@aBxY8KRa00132/YxUqhWMyHBTUfkit79ox2MtM8POW5IRvyBEB6PtBq4Cc8ayMf1vJOXc13G@UC74HXYlG7RYeviWnc5p2pmX8Gx1RCTSy0Q80nGonDMgx7CvxIQnmzNHCGt6rM5Al91kXT5/1ikXAw8ueEwFezfVrkZqp9avK9Uy0LkMzLwUyN7yjDb7/l7E3E6lM1Ku6VK0/3dSabhfbL65rScnpl49fOydXJyZ@1tqrkXhzL9oZcK5hSzixYX7ZM8@PHj4gZmNbSlU5LbW5tFWqlze1Cab9kK6VajgW2ZduaWi5r7Y3wlD2pPXnyRLVPFKVaUU4/0LcIe0/xx//hmr/S/Smvyao5yOr1VGPqrxMp13wCPalsPt1/8lHKSbnzZhGXwe/F4u7uvq7rE/yM4p6U@1gHTL0znRbrrXrdaDYnTb3TbEm5Wyk3mUq5skwMKEi5xqT@hg/QepmNVPz1Z9zqeqc1PPn58OD0sFSu67ny0cGLUvn07fOcjbfq4pUaK/T65vDg5fHbs1JZ9Prjq3eHb09Q7/v@MOl2k43jzeP9btTvNPf3iwYQ3TeaHWA0@aHYLDbSNGW/nBcMJ5ZyL5uTt6ZeBxY/S7k3HFZva4D@IuVauZa6V94rW4F1bdlX9tXr6Hjx7/gY9f7E@hTFVt/q213btieW99a6sW4m1iA6trsoevizBij6Vm9iXVqhFdr2nXEe/jc4jl4fRxgqQrd0YqU0qtXD8/L4@DUG62HiT/jzLYvwm1jX@GcFNr8@nFuaJWFD2KluDsubv7a4aanudFrexE87Misp7ZbSqeXMpN02hS7LZagjNU@n5@cvD84Ozs9N2iFN6vniflHfx9VoFuvZYy/XbRLHjLqkqOP379/T7/34eixKvCDq3s8bl194Adf1A33vFlTVKKz@bds7RhGF4n6r2rmdagx/T9pKTREEqaoHl6nKdntS7rGyzD3RDuyAXUG0r25WtWZzs4r3zW1NVy1q3dA@2PV61lTWolhWJnIUK@x2Kv7U22ld5ZdGf5pGldm9qd2qdYCok9tpVeMVogfgQAWF7/9H/6IEe02m5KY5Much26hq2Bx42samul3cyf4aTzWgLVeUCtCWlZw0k3LDzhGZUs6ovZHtsqyQ1GuU6IoCzwgQgld2JBmXpCDGU2q0Q4QhVrMcU7s9sSyYrdpFI3@bc6Y1SZKnsgDLLuKXUuM5R/lWzjtxy@4AJn97MSUnhatga9zDVDdqtcKGKG9t12poKGQtFlqyIhq8xHG5tsIw8uFBlCY1LrxLP5TqlaZUb95KcKkX4M@YbVkImYLAiVnU6z0V9YgNsKny4Bu9IKDdKYXG4ygOumOEa0@lXOLhGpw43sjzxqPR2JtfL/xk1/n0CSHfkOw3PLolGeR9y@Wd7er2TqW8Xdre2d6o2pvVaskul@yt7a0dqwQDvm1vbld37NL2xk5lY2NjB63VnS0p54Vdv2easJS2LDNeQNxIn6bU6SOeyOg3mZTrej1KSD4J1K72JNedV4y2mVzZblttS5booy2mQiC3tOhVliDCi3qqVRpBzat7o215c0veLeAp78kVFFmgMkuBCGWlLctaa6ezJ29VMdQufIquPLP3mLy1I@/KW1uo1GpTYDejeo43gykwDIafrkvULvyjKm9h4Sk1gNVEl39Z6hNf7WIbH9NegoMj1N7ckakaIPVm9aKwW7L10r4YjG3aUm4qdenQe2OnRj5mWm9KeYUoVipSTq9EG1Eun8/DJZ015Yp8bNTNzNk0Te5s2uR8yNAbUgNzkFrn5NzNZOlqC3CaKpd8iar21/DHWm53qFQ2lEq7kRO2xd7Scs3ylpE4N7mOqGPqxpbG8MaVtGznemN@zU3eigFcKq15H18PuKsEGtt/6F5e@uU/vP74BdslRcGKsTe/6nXxr47bi2OBl7xZlbVcguvD@YdzuO8qk8tVmbGiybDpMv9cho7u7Gxub@ak30zzse0WWufRYs9DIDUarAsXD2L/tUP5rXAeMqLweoR9xVyHGSkxBeL95t06rth3qvh/yUGdRHiRZFUqOPGlW@JJN1agT6laHY3dzhK2KrVSzlCbpxhjLx3FIbNqIhVMQ/i1eRGz0KpgDQLgGUF4AdVv2DXm12kwPBFUZjPQNetRbFCRNjMcC7@j1aTl3CnHpIneS7gs9S8WBfhUoCXocQddQbZom78CvQGdMblq1lu7B9CyOoBR2paSkfk9ZGDXoM5HKLHfTca9/oiftRlNHIVFY1a/EMVUKqSlQU0isgvDmvST6mq3FNfXvg6ePXM/DFuDTk0bNFJ6FouD2lS6Un0BUkgbg4Zu14ZAtpa2ikW/0xhoP6lDjvygYQEYc9PIiXY7l3TYyMSVaKXPrVD/GnZKR62waHdKo1Lhl8bnktOwShP8wLZSUPoVzJuxUk0bn4thzanjR1uMO5wYNpKiU7ub0kaXKzVofG45nYal1QJ0LBaPQAzwTFpBsdjRMHmAxtWOteDZM6cYNCe1QNc1gvpQ2TtqpSh0ig1631Wd@mTvc2uE/rsqng1ME2hAHv3uygDjAb8aeCzEt0Bd4Dgh9CZAb9BoFH7ZK/xSaDx9@rk10QedkmD/rrUQPCE/IeSXdUQt/LKsWJwlPB5Q5R/83R@MQsLkErQPTC4Nl3oKDAu/oGW4WA3T/wU)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.

## Explanation

Klein is a group of 12 languages that are embedded in different topological surfaces.  Klein 201 is embedded on a particular Klein bottle.  In 201 when the ip is deflected off of the north end of the program, it will appear again on the west edge of the program.  The `/` on the first line does just that, deflecting the ip to run the 18th line.  Before we hit the `/` we end up with an extra `1, 6, 125, 40, 111, 43, 63, 50, 51, 33, 64, 45, 32` from the `16` and the `"}(o+?23!@- "`.  So I added the Klein code `**********819+*+@` to the 19th line. The first string of `*`s clears all the garbage we accumulated and the `819+*+` puts the 80 on the stack.  `@` exits the program.

#### Retina

Retina did not like the "nested quantifiers" caused by the long string of `*`s and `+`s.  Prepending each and everyone of these with a `.` was the shortest things I could do to get Retina to not error on this line.

#### The usuals

By now incident and prelude had both broken from the changes.  A bit of space shuffling was required for prelude and some token breaking was required for incident.

#### Moorhens

Unsurprisingly I did not break Moorhens. But I have wanted to move the moorhens code forward for a while now so I did.  The farther forward Moorhen's `os` is the less code Moorhens parses, so we should endeavor to move it close to the beginning to prevent the parsing of as much of the file as possible. I moved the long string of `xi`s up to the Brain-Flak code and replaces them with `no`.  Snoringfrog helped me to clean up some of the leftover code in the Commercial answer.

#### Archway

In order to fill in the space where the moorhens once was, realigning archway, I added a bunch of `x`s and one `y` before some of the archway code.  This is prime place for making and breaking tokens because these can pretty much be any character.

#### Alphuck

Moving some letters around broke alphuck, which Snoringfrog kindly fixed for me.

## Going forward

Klein still has 11 more topological surfaces that can be added to the polyglot.  It might not be the wisest to add all of them (that could be chaos) but a few of them might be easy.  This program also prints 80 in Klein 211 as well.

Comment: Nitpick: I think the Klein code is on line 19, not 18

Comment: "that could be chaos". Wouldn't want to ruin how clean and orderly the code currently is!

Answer (score 8):

## 84. Klein 001, 2336 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#~
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<\>@*99[?]*]*.*|!)'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>{\';   a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003941 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2420 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001

### Verification

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zVvJcttImj4bMW/QlzTIMgCS2EhRCzdJtuUeV5VLGsvLRJG0DIKgCAsEWAAoUpbpmOtMzKHvfZljv0df5yn6RWq@PxNcJFGyK2ImYiATSGT@mflv@S@ZcM9Jhr//nqOLnUTB1XkQpSz1kpT1Y//Siw329IodOH5SLVckiUPFUX/i@uE5S4ce88PxJGUDP/ASyXVS1mLjbBSDCizHYs/pCzBpEMWMurDRRcB85o7HrBc4Q8NlgQ/YF9Yu4JNoRDCpF49jD/eEhZ7XZ8nYc/2B7/K5mDdLvTDxozAxmO9esKkfBKzvBeiwQsAtYTA2SdaqxHSG1I8khssd30J3@Zb3ABN6C5K9sRNzkiM25vQvKJ/GzngMJKUcOwXiqT/yEuanSsI8J/GJj@iSeGGfc2u85HDEnHCdSnbpO8wBvpOYj514cQryDD4uG3qxhyEdmvw8dkZMncZ@ChYQMw/ZiefE7E3seRpmgRC8xHXGwOPGlJgsohlSIsTgwmo0lKPjFwqEJnoYzjiVcnHlzb/8KDnMaLL8WR2/pizXpaNfnrPrfIfKwAKDQbDjWHU01vzKErPT8fCb2T3zPJ5LGFUCVwJmRuPUxMhOnAK9VUm/LBvjYG1a1rgliTVFElB9yIK9DNm7EqfLncSxByxWLHUuQHIQhefgJkiNJyFxI2TbFgTgRmE/KTHvEjyLQiGhaMr5@2boQ2QJCcTpgT2OS5wXi4CzE8sAmpfxczFvEgUTDoeeSUrqB56gK434csDesYHjB9QF7TSUwDr2kkmQUp9J2Ce5j/zQ6xtsgYYb9QloFF1iOgeD8gqsm9HaauNIARhiiDip1PSPv/y1f36OcQ5dN4r7mbK@Y/3InYyAsMORdaCIpK5R6AQcLcCVaHbRHRNcOoHfd1KaPrzKpuBI8Fmn0SToswgTxlMfC2voXGIxDgaem3pCxaNJChxLbORcCBvhC70F4SOnB8HyCfjcnGydHTyDlFxPKIw@mqSDXaaPj5iSmB/U/Zq6/7jjATfN0Ap50zyvQ9uMAq/Cm/KQ4rw7XMmTtOeNH9EqCsbDCWwGWsJkDGsSEzNdB@QkZFRS2L0S63FGc0sERedLdOopscd6WNcLwriOCB2g/jqt22yElUwXcDdVzOuvaRi0E0qWJneMRBBNMTHHjYwndDqkyZ1zB1OlGUGHgiAxI6@5SdpFCE2n0Xoe29V7PqRDegBTkwljjUaAV8oCBqMJ6a0tipFzhVFcYaJXkmT@AEIeQW/jK@Z6tBiwKjxh52iSCVeMxIceRQNm6eVq9RvCT2PzUP/VdPTP5oMyJuJvifmQDbwpC5zwfOKcQ5GjEF0c1/XGabaCQEmSYo3cNoO8Us9supEMpfzB7bm5bcus/docZH2E9DIL7ZDag1EjsFoPsMqZE5/zlcj6foz1Elzdnh0Al7cmlz8SyA0EPsr3oLBwTFAyb@a5kxTLDYo8HfruELpL2IViwQrreHt6VK3PDpOjD5ZTEzJ260lZMsxlFaFx7xA6SfTuOLD6NFTrRgUX/nrFwyM7yWjDwNESRViotVrDdAzoXsY0ePNTiiRg/haum6@sZXix5CcY/CM5ptj7bQKBQZ/985BAnHDp9tcso5@EClyFn/jgOjlw0vU3L4/JH7z3RAwDvgtftm7MI0Q06J45aGpYCEHy3GHE9JApGQ6qzP3pJ6BlJrHLC/paECFrBvikEr9402KgTyI2u@1QWesuHJ9SKbG2LHdL8GFBAhUKJ0GAl0nIl5jqadfQNddLEgMLBrw1KBoBdnLR0@Y3AdNhHE2ZN9fqyqbp/qBAnk16/uz/oURcwkvcQdWaGHjV98jhDuBCELKcse4OBOfds2hEdp695xQTvk9j@IYB/IE0vkqHsHS6y2SnGY09oHTDkijAE8G5qtV5QKcoxqfID9Vr5fHjx0pNaSkllPZRalBpn0pFlPZ5SeclgjOoxHuUeIla27wH1XWVeXsx8kzrkmhnFLV@9seq067VKt2S07azZ5meGpwJfAegdXpgHEVrNqmoaXJrCkKN3kAS5L@BcH5GyMd@9skTDxAgrhIHaTlZR5IFMyo3bam8aimLWPWdOQL7jPHV5ihCXh@Kd3jlhxcR6ag5WpTOLMOu3hgC@c7dngM/GfLbDdA7aN1t4b2TUW/AbxsAalkYgJiCciTiCzdlFIlEETR/ysFGURgJVMAvP3TM1/xhwHtswuemkb6BzFMPa/7c0/cqZs8PzZ43uA/yxdOnLznMoNfz7wMCUwjvxXMDWDzpbeIZYrPhHSfObnD9zSROA71vpvT0/vvf@uD@XdkMnasE0fzFsnAGppGc9MG9osq60gu/bRbrp0mATO8bY7gORfBOsCxsHqvGXnvQfYg15AkeMA0C2BOwDHburnJjXQSTvrd4bh6U8/BmLCB6h/5Ih2ZvGxYXIF4pvuHW555RbgU0YhhKfOIgcvqmSEV9byVRwXtv5pxH4ZW55tmMuPcdqC5iDrbKPdPhJJ2IOyWc35KdP6bfQwsyg7Sqh0/to@xxDzyQ2L5Pd8WyIVOtvwicC7NHxbMBiptJFcTE/jmy28XzPrD3p2PH9cxpQo977Uc4ScZckLx0HxiixzgQ9/tA/NCFZw1XhfsAQWLAb39E67gSuE4A1asIxaP9Hn2NR/4trgZO74r82fCPKxDNel4sMh02pOkWi1aF6dEqIVvtLI3H9/d33az/3t7m3mITig/gRsidvW85JXgWfwQWlPtrxXuVxI/0Vf6XCM2ieGCTMXIuHcQHgZNAV9KM494lJMRvD@kuuQx3EjjxqvSQ5t5CapGD35fGrXqOfTeCcxeqSi@Bv1FbQ4r7bsdIq2Fog5HfVl3pLTOjzxEGkSf@@qAtjdyUsqd71Og7zJNIXCg1XNMLI7qPaW40pd@9K3gYXXrivtktfd6I1XeYHz3gKoHg@273vvstbX3vJzA@uG02ixcbsUrdYGN9jb2KohiZa8LKhvWgeDYq86nx0vjZODZO2akfRMmD/EDeniTivlmVV6C92HdC3SUdXi9v7rYRMe7i2CG/3yNgJziPgu3dc9PB7V4tmMQDsvbZ83uN3NJI2fY3jdQyrIlCO3vea@Iv8O9bCkK7IrDpPsU3y@JmZfmGRcuSgfvJRAZAPTeT@MLaXepYnHgblQtzZzCHsTucOlcPquC3/Ml9zF74kxrt4vNQ@kFkvjnN1sPT9L/PXt0ZdufhYW8I@afAg8G@oPsd0bKyZf/BHrZlfb/1GgQTb@JttCbHvU8eFOch7n4/UpYgg2eir/lxw3L/LyllpySo8@NsVzxZHjzlXoZu7PHdwMX@BsvRHuVkBE@aRrHBOJyqOsWipkmiE9nk8xBgCyi@@U/7r@JcIWFwjimHRQ7dbrP89axm1ew5azK5JrNuV4zKdwKPZmO@a/9adG3nnW4zr@i6klc6YY1ZCgf1AiyMjaDODbiBzx8CzxXpLHRGfMuXygtK62JfGZ6LDhOGTthHCvE29PnWjRvFYndUbMHzdO3vf@tnZyznHogc@YkTgBF0KhiNvGE03RfzZrMfjscOndHQGIhcA7G5oz87ZMnUT92hOFqBY3374s1uti@enVLi5YRyhzUshFDRNAAOTiqEJrDpR57Qo2ziZa8FUYhWJqOQTf1@OkwMuKDQ9fi@@2IvGJjEBBamcUR6WGIvWd@jMJrvTX2aQLZBFF3wLTHC5O9/E6cBaPRJhai8mJ4fT63NyLBUbL4F77rRBFgvBvnsxVEGohKTEXNNwJErrAJP1GvMHTr8mAKaqC826WkasVH/7PCU6UdMocNV2rOv@wM1f/j6z@/aVrf5lY1MZNYmbRNyvsk/6Dt2IpfYAqQ@J71ab7bQvGpVmJyfyRlZdJDHz62WSiVWE1OpzMW12HQf8TNArnfelG@685OVkEJKOlwLE6wPvGp8aLFomnkVKfnIT5l@mrIqnUB7YAlK4tSQ0ZkubSBTl/yMfWFD0hXdZXbVwptgSEBnFqPmaiNkfSfKfO71Jjxjuywb5UqTk5M/azZavBR7/YhOtdofOtOumSy40unMfrDKM7AtigH@xKSVc/TL8@u80bK@fEngi2R5rtT5TiEt7/z1ycuTo9M3h2/enoKNc0Fl7kUUj5yViSAlGAcIFYZRwI8JwY/Y95Jvm41H3G5IjzJAVWV5hzVgmhks1KOlYcnYKutyXhRFG7cky7ZbjZn5GPgsM3XshEs7E6ySrJu50kIBiHlYkxPY1QXyUJzrDeaKkyOzJgjSQRAHXyK8fNtE2M1WDi8Yvk/vYHpGxjoUJ3UFtRmIaBXAGd4CRiC5kYj5/xLmY/iRb2NOUN/CHMDSt2Zfm/jF4cuf374@ujv32rQZzB2QpYasfZdxNENwBzs44BpOp38LvYmy09uFYYDdH4ojBSdYmbZkeTpAmjQgwxxgbdOi4HsnCS1uRnbEYIdBAkPa78My9K5SMiywqOJAYHkqIOfAAGPp50pMlgg2ad49xYPhmCIEdz@KznkOx0dONh2EdzzzH3/5qzj87qQo/3tWHqD8n6L8wSQG3T0tFTguWUNseffyhCXwVoLwkTNbo4kcBjkkP0QI5Y/AwUvOEAIXyK7oXY2jtt@BnxACmEmWj4wdn8@Lu@owTcc10yT/joxmYPAdVW8GOcBWGsgBzN8m9C0C7LO5Xd3esk0gqV8uBuRHXOe0vScG1LQaVEi69MfNjz2XNRoNJieuE3jN7bpgpJl3PlTkj0tE84CVRCjQZuiDLqseaGtl3dS8U7Q16kqrULEV1q3Dywu5wFGovAAQjarDjB8yPFGUsYpOy7xZyo3q1SLEQXwRRmxEfOJfpCwG0jGQGFuTpTu6C3zRwvfw/BuxpbEuBvk9gfEdv5q8SXUYNOS/NmhOiPJ/iHK7Y@lfu5u@pljqzuHdjybU2588EC3s4DSMaFv3BXBlatksV0x7W1tbJ3I2FLClVfEFQ2IdYF25nv8pGieHz45e/nh8cnrn0J9DKrfBFKa0GsWObpTa3WVBuaXzC5Y@fWGevnr6YsHIdayypttYbRr8NmL3TPZebJrenYo33JnItr534FXms5GQVV60BvhMbOjcmVXVruftbqPVCXN3pv@y6YucnFGgj3BQ6iT8exyFbTAwLxdbwW@iC6jHA58a6ClB@J/XPzpYbCTTiX65Zfa9S5OOoCVjtcUs59XGDWw18VmE4MFietiJrCaPTK3FVnO50p3duXVExAZJtMTkRs8ls4nmY5HZ8a@KnBBBfey7AjrhxlXkf/wTGGQAL9NV0oBEhDJRnhtd8TwAy3y529X3@UaoE19lFCxbTr2Rr79Z4EOLfnXOCyMUxSnSj2QY@L2602zP2PIU9KEjYCMZB36q0tnrzKD8CtSoGhFgNwKPjm4be93snJgtjnOL/ET4ZAJ@nURjtsppn3uL0mukNez5BINDAzz242QEuAF/vPbIwnvsl0hHZ/BRWSDRxixqRoMx6lcxuzH0Zn3/HF5C1UowKD/Y9uos2dGKyEUV2FDBqj/TFt46Y/7Q@fcax5y2Y/hh35upylTRal3iDuqV6ftLRZPv6AA/hM9O5Pu3T@MXa99Js0W4PMleXziLgAWTZ@dgcCL0jSR9/YBEwYdOH/zkhSFURgXaIygIcyagM9ZKiw91S8vPqtbswj9nx2q3vcSRch1E8IV5s85TkvocDuFjh3XSzqATkleoX5l/Mg2zfq3mg@aVCUeutdT8sGkXK4ViMR8W1HxIruzJE8pk5nl4yjNDNuQZgPR8oNXBT3jWZj6s552Gmu83ywXeA6/FonaNDl8T07jOO3Mz/wSOqYSaWGiHmk80EodlGPYc@JGE8mZp5IyvVZnJM/o6jabP@8Ui4WDkzwiBr2bntMjNVOfU5LlTPQuQzPPRQo1vKMPvv@fsbcTqczUq7pcrjw90JpuFzvPLutJ2BmXjt@7JxcnJv2odVck9O5btLbleMKWcWbC@7Jjmx48fETMwra0r3bba2tkp1Evbu4XSQclWSvUcC2zLtjW1XNY6W@Epe1R/9OiRap8oSrWinH6gTyr2H@OP/8O1fKX7Y16TVXOQu9djjam/zaRc6xH0pLL9@ODRRyn3VcqdtYq4DH4vFmu1A13XZ/gZxX0p97EBoEZ3Pi822o2G0WrNWnq31ZZy11JuNpdyZZk4UJByzVnjNR@g/Twbqfjbz7g19G57fPLz0eHpUanc0HPlF4fPSuXTt09zNt6qq1dqrNDr66PD58dv35TKotefX747enuCet/3x0m/n2wdbx8f9KNht3VwUDSA6IHR6gKj2Q/FVrGZpin79axgOLGUe96avTX1BrD4Wcq95rB6RwP0FynXzrXV/fJ@2QqsS8u@sC9eRcerf8fHqPdn1qcotobW0O7btj2zvLfWlXU1s0bRsd1H0cOfNULRtwYz69wKrdC2b4xz/7/RcfTqOMJQEbqlMyulUa0BnufHx68w2AATf8Kfb1mE38y6xD8rsPn14czSLAkZYbe6PS5v/9bmtqW61217Mz/tyqykdNpKt54zk07HFMosl6GP1Dyfn509P3xzeHZmUoo0a@SLB0X9AFezVWxkj/1cv0UcMxqSok7fv39Pv/fTy6ko8YKoe79sXH/hBVyX9/S9WVBVo3D3b9feM4ooFA/a1e71XGP4e9RR6oogSFU9@ExVtjuz8oCVZe6K9mAI7ArCfXW7qrVa21W8b@9qumpR65b2wW40sqayFsWyMpOjWGHXc/GnXs8bKr80@tM0qszuLU1Fs1bF2@xanTXUhkp1qKJe1/MWFTncXJRwxxAgkEL7/6N/UYI8lCm5eY5Mfci2qhoSB0/b2lZ3i3vZX/MxUFflilIBRbLiKO32QaFS2Nlq73cL3YLa6LQOCnt74s0ofHmsKTlpoSRNO0dcknJG/bVsl2WFlKZOG2VR4BkBQvjKniTjkpRG6xrigQWFIVezPapOZ2ZZMHv1XjN/nXPmdUmS5zKHWlzEbqXO9yzlaznvxG27C5j8dW9OTg5Xwda4h6pu1euFLVHe2a3X0VDIWiy0ZEU0eInjcmWHYeXDg3BNava8cz@U4Ip74N2U7VgItYLAiVk0GDwW9YgpkIx58KleEFBWSyH1NIqD/hRh3mMpl3i4RieON/G86WQy9ZbXMz@pOZ8@IVQck91HJGBJBnntcnlvt7q7Vynvlnb3dreq9na1WrLLJXtnd2fPKsHw79rbu9U9u7S7tVfZ2traQ2t1b0fKeWHfH5gmDKwty4wXEG/SlzkN@oYpMoYtJuX63oA2Mh8Fal97lOsvKya7TK7sdqyOJUv0zRpTIYhrshUqSxAZRgPVKk2wOqr7k115e0euFfCU9@UKiixQmaVAdLLSkWWtvdfdl3eqGKoGX6QrT@x9Ju/syTV5ZweVWn0O7BZUL/FmsCCGwfDTdYnahV9V5R2sV6UOsLro8k9rfeKLGtL/mHIQDo4QfXtPpmqANFrVXqFWsvXSgRiMbdtSbi716cx/a69OrmneaEl5hShWKlJOr0RbUS6fz8OTvWnJFfnYaJiZj2qZ3Ed1yGeRfzCkJuYgdc7JuavZ2tUR4I2vOX5Ky06uaasp@4y19gpzqU7tlH@u1O4y7esvfnC9W9FbPG5D/Dhnc0Izl3yJqvbX8Md6rjZWKltKpdPMCXNm72i5VnnHSJyrXFfUMXVrR2N444pdtnODKb@WVvaOzV0rbXifXo64dwYau3/qn5/75T@9@vgFKZqigBp7@6veEP8auD07FnjJ21VZyyVJ8uHsw1lOylWZXK7KjBVNhjzP/Ncy1Htvb3t3Oyf9bpoPZXhoXQaoAw@x22S0KUI9jP1XDm2phcsoFYVXE6QyS/VnpP8U@w9bN@v4mrhRxf8zE@okwouUQqWCE5@7Jb7Pxwr0EVq7q7HrxR6xSq20TaktdzVjL53EIbPqYveZhvDryyJmoQXFmgTANyHhd1S/adeZ36DB8EQcm81A16JHsUlFyp84Fn5Xq0vr27UckxZ6r@Gy1r9YFOBzgZagxx31BdmibfkK9EZ0rOWqWW/tFkDb6gJG6VhKRub3kIFERV2OUGJ/mIxb/RGyawuaOAqrxqx@JYq5VEhLo7pEZBfGdekn1dWuKZWofx09eeJ@GLdH3bo2aqb0LBZH9bl0ofoCpJA2R03dro@BbD1tF4t@tznSflLHHPlR0wIw5qaRE@16KemwmYkr0Uqf26H@NeyWXrTDot0tTUqFX5ufS07TKs3wA9tKQek3MG/BSjVtfi6GdaeBH2U1NzgxbiZFp35zFx1dLtSg@bntdJuWVg/QsVh8AWKAZ9IOisWuhskDNN7tWA@ePHGKQWtWD3RdI6gPlf0X7RSFbrFJ7zXVacz2P7cn6F9T8WximkAD8uh3UwYYD/jVwWMhvhXqAscZoTcDeqNms/DrfuHXQvPx48/tmT7qlgT7a9ZK8IT8jJBf1xG18Ou6YnGW8BBClX/waz8YhYTJJWgfmFwar/UUGBZ@Rct4tRrm/wM)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/) *I have not acutally installed or tested Objeck, However I believe that it works based on the description of how the last answer worked*

### Explanation

Klein, is a family of 2 dimensional languages that can be embedded on different topological surfaces.  Klein 001 is embedded in a Klein bottle.  When the ip is deflected to the north, in Klein 001, it reappears on the south edge but mirrored across the vertical axis.  For example if we had the following:

```
. ^ . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
```

(Where `^` indicates the position of the ip moving north.)  The ip would appear to the south as such:

```
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . ^ .
```

Since our polyglot deflects Klein languages off the top in the 19th column from the west this means our ip will reappear in the 19th column from the east.  This column is mostly empty; only one row is long enough to reach all the way to the east.  Funnily enough it is the 19th row.  The 19th row is where the other two Klein languages we have added exist.  Klein 201, will do us no harm because its all the way to the west, but Klein 100 is an issue, we the entirety of the Klein 100 program to exist in the last 18 characters of line 19.  Despite SnoringFrogs best efforts, Klein 100 took up far more than the last 18 characters, this meant I had to golf it down quite a bit.  Here is the original program:

```
@*99.?.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
```

All the dots are to prevent Retina's "nested quantifier" error (we will find this to be a big pain later on).  After a lot of effort I was able to get it down to

```
@*99.?]*]*.*<
```

How does it work? Well the biggest part of the program is getting rid of the crud already on the stack, this is done by multiplying everything into one massive value and throwing that out with a `?`, the old version just had all the multiplications in a row, however this version sets up a loop of sorts.  To do this we use a feature rather unique to Klein languages, the "door".  There are 2 doors `]` and `[` each allows the ip to pass through it when the ip is approaching from the concave side of the bracket, but reflects the ip when it touches the flat side.  The unique thing about doors is that when the ip touches a door of one type it switches to become a door of the other type.  Here we start with the doors shut, the ip runs through a few `*`s and opens the door, it then goes back to the start, gets turned around by `<` runs again opens the *second* door runs back and forth one more time.  If you have ever done the exercise called "suicides" this works exactly like that.

So I after golfing down the Klein 100 I was able to add the Klein 001 right before it like so:

```
@*3*74.?]*]*.*<xxx@*99.?]*]*.*<
```

The `x`s are placeholders, because the Klein 100 is now so short we need to pad it (this won't last very long)

### Every single language that uses square brackets for loops

Turns out there are a lot of these, and they don't appreciate it when you have unbalanced square brackets in your code.  So I had to balance the doors in the new Klein code:

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<xxx@*99[?]*]*.*<
```

### Perl, Prelude and Retina

I swear these three languages were conspiring against me.  Perl takes issue with the unbalanced `<`s so I have to replace them with something else or balance them.  This isn't too hard Klein 001's `<` can be balanced, but we have to get rid of Klein 100's `<`, no biggie we have `x`s lying around anyway,

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<\>x@*99[?]*]*.*|!
```

Ok now prelude is outputting a null byte, `!` is preludes output command so we need to avoid that.  No problem, `?` also jumps in Klein and has the advantage of also popping a value so we'll do:

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<\>x@*99[?]*]*.*|?
```

However Retina doesn't like that because `?` is a quantifier in Retina and thus `|?` is invalid regex.  Usually this is fixed by adding a dot before the quantifier, but since the `?` is there to skip the `|`, putting a dot pretty much makes the `?` useless.  So I tried a couple of things.

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<\>@*99[?]*]*.*<>?
```

Breaks Retina

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<\>@*99[?]*]*.*<>!
```

Breaks Prelude

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*.*<\>@*99[?]*]*.*[?[?]?]?
```

Too long

I spent a good deal of time on this problem, each solution seemed to just barely break in one of the three answers or required more space than I had available.  The way I managed to get past this was to put a prelude jump to prevent prelude from executing the `!`.

```
[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<\>@*99[?]*]*.*|!)
```

I feel rather lucky that this solution takes the *exact* amount of space we are allowed for the answer.

### Tips going forward

Despite how difficult it was to get this to work, it is quite robust, here is a list of things that may or may not harm Klein 001

### Will not harm

- Adding characters to line 19 before the relevant section.  Since the Klein code is relative to the end of the line making the line longer will not effect it
- Adding new lines to the polyglot.  As long as there are less lines than there are characters on the 19th line adding new lines won't mess up Klein 001

### Might harm

- Making a line within 19 of the length of line 19.  If another line gets within 19 of the east edge Klein 001 will start executing its code, unless the line is *above* line 19.  Depending on what it is it might interfere with Klein 001.  The main thing to worry about is things that might deflect the ip off of its path

### Will harm

- Adding to the end of line 19.  This will mess up the alignment wreaking havoc on Klein 001
- Making another line longer than line 19.  Since Klein 001 is relative to the longest line making a different line longer will change Klein 001's alignment
- Moving the 19th character.  If the `/` in line 1 is moved it will completely realign Klein 001.

Answer (score 8):

## 91. [Cood](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/), 2623 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.xxxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppp
More 91 of thisof re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main (  ){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv m>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003480 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2709 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTtNd9pKluvozD/oTVniRRKgLzA2RoDtl9jdef3S9sROMidAHCEKUCwkniQMDiGntzNnFr3vzSz7f/S2f0X/kTf3VkmADbbzzsycM7ItlapuVd2vuh9VcteJh7/@KuFFzkP/duCHCUlonJBe5N3QSCc/3pIjx4srpbIgMKgo7E1cLxiQZEiJF4wnCel7Po0F10lIk4zTUXQsEIlE1OlxMKEfRgS7kNG1Tzzijsek6ztD3SW@B7CnZhXg43CEMAmNxhGFe0wCSnskHlPX63sum4vQWUKD2AuDWCeee02mnu@THvWhwwoBtwiDkUm8VsWn04VeKBC43PE9dJdvOQowAc1IpmMnYiSHZMzozyifRs54DEgKErkAxBNvRGPiJXJMqBN7yEfoEtOgx7g1XnI4JE6wTiW58RziAL6TiI0d0ygB8nQ2LhnSiMKQDk4@iJwRUaaRlwALkJnH5Jw6EbmMKFVhFhACjV1nDHjcmRImC3GGBAnRmbDqdfnk7FQGofEeujNOBCkqX/7rT4JD9AbJXdnw1xBFWzj500syz7WxDFjAYCDYcaQ4Kml8I7HRblP4m1ldYxAtBBhVAK74xAjHieFoY0BQSwBBw8EilrSbkj721yYm9XuyWFMlDtUDaZBXAXlXZJS5kyiigMeKqc41EO2HwQD4CcRGkwD5EZA9E0TghkEvLhJ6A1wLAy6jcMo4fDn0QGgxisTpAoMcF3nPlwFjKCwE0L2Uo9m8cehPGBz0jBNUQOAKdMURX/XJO9J3PB@7QDsOxbGOaDzxE@wzCXoo@ZEX0J5OMjTcsIdAo/AGpnNgUFYBK2e0tt4YUgAMgggZqdj0z7/8tTcYwDjHrhtGvVRd35Fe6E5GgLDDkHVAFVFhw8DxGVoAV8TZeXeY4MbxvZ6T4PTBbToFQ4LNOg0nfo@EMGE09WBpDZ0bWI79PnUTypU8nCSAY5GMnGtuJTyuuUD4yOmCYNkEbG5GtkaOXoCUXMpVRhtNkn6VaOMTIsfGR@WwphzutCngpupqPmcYAxv0Tc@zKniTH1Ocd8creaL2XHohriN/PJyA1YCWIB6DPYmQma4D5MRoVhKwfEXSZYxmtghUnS3SKZUjSrqwsjPCmI5wHcD@Gq7cdISVTDO4uypGe2saBtoJSpbEG2bCD6cwMcMNzSfodICTOwMHpkpSgo45QXxGVnOXtOsANB1H61JS1boeSAf1AIxNKow1GgG8XOIwMBqX3tqiGDm3MIrLjfRKksTrg5BHoLfRLXEpLgZYFZRbOpxkwhQj9kCPwj4xtVKl8oTwk8g41j6A9fhiPCpjJP6emI9Jn06J7wSDiTMARQ4D6OK4Lh0n6QoCSuIE1sh9Q8gqtdSq6/FQyB3dn5tZt9Ter82B1odLL7XRDqo9MGoErNZ8WOXEiQZsJZKeF8F68W/vzw4AN/cmFz8hyB0EPokPoJC5JlAyOqPuJIHlBoo8HXruEHQXsQv4guXW8f70ULU@O5gcrb@cGpGxms9Lgm4sqxCNB4fQUKKb44DVx6GadyqY8NcrHh/ZiUdbBg6XKIKFWqvVDUcH3UuZBv78AmMJMH@Z82YraxlgLPkJDP4JHVNEf5mAwECfvUGAIE6wdPxrltGLAxlchRd7wHV04ajrl6/O0B@8pzyKAb5zX7ZuzEOIaaB76qKxIROCQN1hSLSAyCkOisg86mdAy4gjlxW0tTBCVHXgk4L8Yk3ZQJ95dHbfoZLmJhybUi6Slih2iuDD/BhUKJj4PrxMArbEFKrOQddcGsc6LBjgrY7xCGAnFqi6uAuYDKNwSuhCteVt0/1GgbyYdL3Z/0OJuIgXvwNVa2JgVd8jhw3ATBCimLJuA4Lx7kU4QjtP3jOKEd8fI/ANffAHwvg2GYKl01wiOo1wTAGlO5ZEBjwhPFdUm4V0sqx/Dr1Amcs7OztyTW7KRSgdQqmOpUMsFaB0yEoaKyGcjiXWo8hK2NpiPbCuIy9a2cgztYOinWHc@sUbK06rVit3ik7LSp8lfKrgTMB3ALSGDxhHVhsNLKqq2JwCoXq3L3DyL0E4P0PIR3720BP3IUBcpQ7CcrK2IHJmlO/aUnHVUuLR6o0xAvbp49vtUYS4PhTrAAHcdYg6uipdmbpVuTMEZDybPftePGS3O6AbaG22sN7xqNtnty0AtTQMgJgCsyTkCzNlGImEIWj@lIGNwiDkqAC/vMAx3rCHDt5jGz53jfQdZLoU1vyAGl0vwPITYNpBlUH2u13vIVDgC6KePbeARZPuNrZBeDbc8OPkDuOTSZT4tJc@//HnHghgUzxD5zaGgP56WbgCvqGotP6D0kq74gu7bZfs54kP6d4TY7gOBvGOvyxsH6tG3lBQf5BswLI8wNQH2jDCAVO3qd@wNPxJj2bP7YMyHt4NB3jvwBsxycETYxtmeR7ofi@Y4f0x6Yn80OkZPBH16EqUnOl05gzC4NZY82p61P0OHLN4g6wyz2Q4SSb8jsnmU0Lzxvj32GJMIc2K07WoEcZO13uAg4jE3kNKy9cCmmmt7zvXvHiFxe2kcmIibwCZbfZ8CAyiPQjIx45LjSl7PGg/gkk8ZsJkpUfGi3x@fwjEC1zwrMGq8BAgkOmz229ROaYILqwDRBU3e7Q1Fnn3mOo73Vt0ZcPfrj844aBQIBrYjoZbKJhlooWrXGy1rTQeP9zfddP@Bwfbe/MdKDaAG0LaTJ/yR@BUvJHja6XeWvFB@5q5/lVpm/lxbhwICnwnBgVJUjbTGxALuz2mtOgn3InvRKvSIyq7QidLuR/K2lZ9xp4b@l6qmdnLlgkCDPPuh0SrYXBHkd1WXfEtNZkvIepBx/vtUbsZugkmSw@ozndYJJ6nYCa4pgt6@BC73HCKfw8u2GF4Q/l9uwv6shWr77A4ms@UAWLtze499ykNxX0gdttuCa@3YpW4/tb6GnkdhhEkqjEp6eaj4tmqxrHnhzG5YPfHeAEpehzz@3YFXmeb5wSaO@TLalne3m0rUsyjkWN2f0C4jj8I/b3qwHDg9qAGTKI@Gvb0@b1GbWmULOtJo7QMX8LASp8PWvNr@H1KOXADBMy3h3HMsrhdUR60YGnE/zCBEObjhtd24k7N6lKzopg@qlI1chy5w6lz@yjUU57jITZnnqOGm/UsEP6fTbP7@DS977NSG8PuPz7sHfFe@xTMNLtvCJWUTOs39rBM8/ttVt@f0AndakPOup8pKM53B8WPImWmZNTIl2v/0TG/C2304vj2qM1xfA/W@ZMxTI2cQxB9Hj6RAAyCyfiOLNezh0nw5rHOLMt@w45SlnubcTE9A4I6L0p3/OPlsZr0KnAjynY6s70bIuH@62QEAUMSRjphcIriFAqqKvBO6IAGAYBlUOxgA/eW@ZlJTCASSBis1yetFsnNZzWzZi1Ig4g1kXQ6fFS2y3kyG7MTiTe8ayvndBo5WdPknNwOasSUGSj1wR5sBXXuwPU99uB4rkgngTNi29lYzii1@Z45uGk8KBk6QQ9SpLeBx7al3DDiO7/8eOES88@//62Xnh8NKBA58mIQ/iDAM89wRIfh9JDPm85@PB47eP6EY0BU7vONK@3FMYmnXuIO@bERRBFvTy@r6Z5/egYLL@eYG61hwYUKTX3AwUm40Dg2vZByrUgnXvbKiILQbDIKyNTrJcNYB58buJSdKWT73IBJhGBBEoWoVUXyivQopghs3@3zBGTrh@E12@5DTP7@N37SAY0eqhCWs@nZ0dvajASWisWOF1w3nADW2SBfaBSmIAoyGQLMCXDkFnSa8nqVuEOHHcGAJmrZAQROww8hXhxfEO2EyHh0jOcRttdXcsdvfv@uZXYa38jIoP/4s4FboIxv4g/avhWLRZKB2AvUq/VmE5pXrTIRczMxJQsPKdmZ3FKp@GoiCpaZuLIDhRE732R6R6fsQIGdGgUYP@PBYRDD@oBXlQ3NF00jp0x8b@QlRLtISAXP1ymwBEr8RJTgiTVujmOX3Ix8JUPUFc0lVsWEN84QH89jRo0fs92b8voum/GSdicsI70p6aVyg5GTu2rUm6wU0V6IJ3atj@1px4gzrrTbsx/M0gzYFkYA/tzAlXPyp5fznN40v36NwQWL4kK22S4oLu/c/PzV@cnF5fHl2wtg44JTKZ2G0chZmQhUgrEPsdEw9NkRKPAj8mj8tNl4xuyG8CwFVBSSc0gdPBIBC/VsaVhStoqamONF3sYsybLtXmNqPvoeSU0dOWfSTgUrx@tmrpgpADIP1uQE7GqGPCjOfIu5YuSIpAEEaUAQA18ivHzbRtjdVgbPGX6I78D0lIx1KEbqCmo7ENLKgVO8OQxHcisRi/8lzMfgR57GHKGewhyAhadmX5v49PjVz2/fnGzOvTZtCrMBstSQta9OTmYQ04Id7DMNx5PNTG/C9GQ6Mwxg94f8uMTxV6YtXp58oCb10TD7sLZxUbB9oRgXN0E7opNjPwZD2uuBZejeJmhYwKLyw47liYcoAQP0pZ8rElFA2LixeUIJhmMKOYf7iXfOMTg2crztkL9NjX/@5a/8YL@dQPnf03Ifyv/Jyx8NZNDmSTDHcckaZMu7V@ckBm/FCR85szWa0GGgQ/ICiBy9EXDwhjEEwTmyK3pX4yitd8BPEAIwEy0fGjs2H406yjBJxjXDQP8OKVxfZ1vFdAZyAFupQ9Jj/DLB7yzAPht7lb1dywAktZtsQHZ8N8DtSz6gqtZAhYQbb9z41HVJvV4nYuw6Pm3s2ZyRRs75WBY/LRHNAazAQ4EWgT7QZdUD2pppNyXnFCwVu@IqlC2ZdGzw8lwu4CgUVgAQFauDlB8ieKIwZRWeBNJZwozqbRbiQHwRhGSEfGJf22QDaTAQH1sVhQ3dXW1T4vHMmjbr62IQ3yPYBYLVxG2qQ0BD/muL5gRQ/g9ebrVN7Vtn25ciS9053vwgRLn/OQfSQo4ughC3rU8BV6KUjFLZsPbUtXUipkMBtrgqvsKQsA5gXbnU@xyO4@MXJ69@Oju/2PiggUHK98FkIjfrhbamF1udZUG@p/MZS388NS5e/3iaMXIdq7TpPlbbBr@P2AOTvecbwptTsYaNiSzzewdmp5faKUuQthCybDXWAF/w3auNWRV1vmh16s12IG1M/3Xb10aSnscPjKDUjtm3RjLZYmBeZdvcl@E1qMcjn1FoCUJ4X9Y/qMg2yfFrhVLT6NEbA4/XBX21fS7mlPodbFX@yQfnQTY92Im0JgcJapOs5nKFja3IdUT4jlC4xOROzyWzkeYzntmxL6acAIL6yHM5dMyMK8//2Oc9kAG8SlZJAyQimICz3OiW5QGwzJdbez2P7fo60W1KwbLlgo487TLDBxf96gwbjFAYJZB@xEPf69pOozUjyxPex4639Xjse4mC58ozHfMroEZRkQCr7lM8lq4fdNIzcJIdVRfYaff5BPh1Ho7JKqd9SbPSG0hryEvIrT3QAEp@mowArs8ebyhaeEr@FGrQGfgoZ0i0YBYlpUEf9Sowuz6ks543AC@hqEUwKD9Y1uqc3FELkIvKYEM5q36Pe5brjPlNZ/trHHNaju4FPTpT5Kms1jrIHaiXp@9vZFXc0AH2gUH6tUHv/pcG2dp3knQRLk/p1xdOFrDA5Ok5HzgR/P4Tv@yARMEDnT76Iw0CUBkF0B6BghBnAnRGajH7DLm4/GRszS78IT02vO8lTuS5H4IvzBk2S0nsBTiET23STtr9doBewb41fmfohj1Xcn7j1gBHrjaV3LBhFcr5QiEX5JVcgK7s@XPMZBY58JRXuqiLMwDScr5qAz/BszZygZ1z6kqu1yjlWQ94LRTUOXT4Fhv6POcsjNxzcExFqIm4dii5WEVxmLpuLQA/lFDOKI6c8VwRiTjDL@9w@pxXKCAOeu4KEfhmtC8KzEy1LwyWO9lpgGQMRpka31GGX3@VrD2I1Q/3ykp4WCrv5CUiHYlGvv3yw4cXN7bccvol/ZfO@fX5@b@pbUWWXpyJ1q5ok7whSEbe/LpvGJ8@fYLQgbSaelPvqC1N7rSU5v5@3i7uVfPFo6IlF22J@JZpWapSKqkX7d3AfgaXYp3LcqUsX3zET0cOd@CH/cK1fMX7DqtJqxnI5rWjEuWXmSA1n4HOlPd2jp4BSrTArlrtiAjSN0G6FaRP9U@CBJGQ1Gx2FotCvVWv683mrKl1mi1BmgvSbCFIJRFZkBekxqz@hg3RetnkYxV@AXb@DM@61mmNz38@Ob44KZbqmlQ6PX5RLF28/VGy4K2yesXGMr6@OTl@efb2sljivX7/6t3J23Oo9zxvHPd6cS8cdppHRwVd07QjvdkBfGY/FJqFRpIk5MNVXp/xa/ds7@xIkF42Z28NrQ6o/CxIb1gvrQ3ItVXo@1WQWlJLOSwdlkzfvDGta@v6dXi2@j07Q7UQ96tiGB4BiDczP4eROTSHVs@yrJlJ35q35u3MHIVnVg@KFH7MERQ9sz8zB2ZgBpZ1Z8iHf0dn4euzEIYKoVsyMxMc1ezDc3B29hoG68PEn@HHM01EdWbewK/pW@z6eGWqZrstQLrYqeyNS3u/tJjhqRx0WnTmJR2RFOV2S@7YkhG32wbXdLEEaorNi8XV1cvjy@OrKwPzp1k9VzgqaEdwNZqFevo4lHpNZKFe32kLsjJ9//49/r2f3kx5iRXeT8n79Joub2vP91O4bh7ofLeAu5ytSme@UAn8PGvLtszxVhQKflMRrfas1CclkbmjAzAGVhlCfmWvojabexV436uqmmJi66760arX06aSGkaiPBPDSCbzBf9R5ou6wi4Vf1QVK9N7U1WgWa3A22yuzOpKXcE6qMJe80UTiwxuDqWWonbUxYLXwV1R63zMpgpkYcD/f/QbxpCdEllaSOgAArJbUSGdoOrunlItHKQ/jR0gRhHLchloFGVHbrWO8uX8/m7rsJPv5JV6Xs@3m53Z@qXKEgHlynSkYUnIPUHS7TeiVRJl1BkbN9FCn@o@hPflA1tW8vevqnVQyBeOWvmDAz5ZPv91R4XeMLYIlwRqRRRSb9azDQVltbegNuFvTlL@EnUxB31I28CDKOnmWLs9M00Gb3cbubnkLGw2PFmIS3C@f86GV2Sb7ZqKczHnRC2rIy7E3Ly7QDebt1TmICu7tp3f5eX9qg123cqnLSa0pEVooLHjsuUEphwVSQYOq0BUo0sHXiBIY8HGHUS@XSlqIldmUj1gnaQ4FiBc6IIkp2TfhHDQ952IhP3@Dq@HuAcSRgp@n/o@Zt4Y9k/DyO9NIRTdEaSYwjU6d@iE0ulkMqXL64UX15zPnyGchUt4jfnmgcV3370YHpDA/wFmHU3cIZ5neAm6LohpTEFHDEulg2qlelAuVYvVg@puxdqrVIpWqWjtV/cPzCJ4raq1V60cWMXq7kF5d3f3AForB/uCRIOe1zcMcBOWKBJWgMgZP56q42dmoT5sgtvp0b4X0GdkpvTUZ1IvqyCTKhHL1bYJwTp@WIjqoM7RrikkhhAXEFfM4gTWeOVwUhX39sVaHp7ioViGIhPzTCGmDPogym1RVFsHnUNxvyLWwJdq8nPrkIj7B2JN3N8XVVukg4oo7pHSvmgvANOMA0saCJg@XSfwp2kCtvNoQRH3wQLJNoDZvMu/rPWJrmtx4kSYWTFwSDz2DkSsBpA61@9mpZuvFS2teMSHJHuWIC2EHn68sXtgo8sFK1RvCjkZ2SCXBUkrh7uhlMvlwFFfNsWyeKbXjdT7Ng3metvojdHj6ZkzbwoRxV3dHv4nEjek1YpqY2UsNKBesHEVilK67G/R9bX5kPVvEjuYJ@fz5W5f@qVy7TUgpTi1C/ZVWgvW5rc/ef68WtaaLHyFMHpBIGJYjC8OPu5/rH58/fbs7dnpUa1aq8LSlOKvalixvgU/2VJtLJd35TI46IbEEbT2ValZ2tdj51bqpOdHyu6@SuCNLbySJfXRpSw9yqbHWStteZ/ejFjcAohUf9cbDLzS715/@goJrCwTYuX2vml1/luH24szLiFF3KuIKizZ@OPVxytJkCpELFVEQgoGhH2G8W8lWDMHB3vVPUn41TAeS4ChdRm/9ymEtpPRtgD@OPJeO7jjGCyDeCi8nkCmt1xTBBcVpkbD5t06ttDuVLH/ZIM6AfFCrVKw4EQDt8i2QUkev0FsdVQyz7bQFWzFXVx1uekb0WQSBcS0@eY8DuHZyyLMgsuUNBCAaQy4ZMVrWDbx6jgYPCHMT2fAK@tRaGAR00uGhddRbWF9N5th0oTea7is9S8UOPiCo8XpcUc9TjZvW74CeiM89XOVtLd6D6BldgBGbptySub3kAF5nLIcoUh@Mxn3@kNGo2Y0MRRWjWn9ShQLIZ8UR7aAZOfHtvBHxVXnmGnZ30bPn7sfx61Rx1ZHjQSfhcLIXgjXisdB8klj1NAsewzI2kmrUPA6jZH6R2XMkB81TACGuXHkWJ0vJR00UnHFavFLK9C@BZ3iaSsoWJ3ipJj/0PhSdBpmcQZ/wLaiX/wFmJexUkkaXwqB7dThD5O@O5wYN@KCY989ZIAu14rf@NJyOg1TtX3oWCicAjGAZ9zyC4WOCpP70LjZ0fafP3cKfnNm@5qmItTH8uFpK4FCp9DA95ri1GeHX1oT6F9T4NmAaXwVkId@d2UA4wF@NvCYi2@FOsdxhujNAL1Ro5H/cJj/kG/s7HxpzbRRp8jZXzNXgkfkZ4j8uo4o@Q/risVYwgIdRfzBq/2g52MiFkH7gMnF8VpPjmH@A7SMV6th8d8)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)

## Explanation

Cood is a language that is meant to resemble a conversation between a waiter and a patron.  It has a rather straight forward syntax.

Based off of the esolangs article on Cood I wrote the following program in Cood to print 91:

```
Hey, waiter!
I want 91 of this.
How much is it?
The bill, please.
```

After playing around with the interpreter a bit I realized I could remove a couple of things bringing me down to:

```
I want 91 of this
How much is it
```

I took this code and inserted it in the place I thought it would fit best, right after the Commercial code, since the two have similar syntax.

### Alphuck

Since I added letters to the source Alphuck had to be fixed.  I followed standard procedure to fix this.

### Grass

The new code added two `w`s which were an issue for Grass.  I was able to remove one of them by changing `I want 91 of this` to `More 91 of this`.  This adds 91 instead of setting it.  Since the cells are initialized to zero and there is no valid Cood code earlier (no surprise there), this has the same function.  The other `w` I was not able to get rid of, so I deleted a `w` later on in the Grass code which caused it to have the correct number of `w`s in its block.  We don't have any `w`s left to delete so if any more lowercase `w`s are added to the code we are going to have to rework Grass a bit.

### Archway

Removing a `w` from the Grass offset the Archway code, I inserted an additional character to get it back.

### evil

evil gave me quite a hard time.  I tried a number of things but what ended up working best was moving the Cood down below the evil.

### C

Moving Cood below the evil moved it out of the C comments requiring me to move the comment down to the end of the Cood, It was then that I discovered that Cood is very lenient with what it considered "punctuation", allowing me to use `*/` as punctuation for the Cood code.

### Incident

As always Incident broke.  I'm just going to list the fixes as bullet points for ease of reading.

- `w` got tokenized. I added a space to the Grass code to detokenize it
- `of` got tokenized. I added another `of` after the first line of Cood.
- `re` got tokenized.  I added a `re` after the `of` to fix.
- `e` got detokenized.  I swapped the tab and the space in the first `#define` line of the C code.
- `s\n` was also briefly tokenized but the `of` took care of that

### Prelude

Adding the space to the Grass code to detokenize Incident upset Prelude.  I had to remove a later space on the same line to realign all of the parentheses.

### Moving on

Cood probably wont break.  It has really specific and permissive syntax.  The only downside to this addition is that it made Grass a little harder to fix if more `w`s are added. However I think this should be still not very difficult to do.

Answer (score 8):

## 95. Emoji, 2777 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8               (1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>  
# 36!@  `  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?24O6O@?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))    \';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define  x(d)   #d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof( "(\"           ); print'(''72'')';end!"           ); main( ){puts("92" );return 0;}
#if 0 
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8 dggi2 M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

(Emojis broke something in the pretty printer of the test driver. I manually fixed the above code.)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003238 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2864 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvLcttKdmuj8gezaYG8BkASL1KU@JZ0bWnGd66vFEu2p0zSMgg2SVh48AKgSJmma1apSiqLqVmlaqry2M0ifzHb@Yr5gvzBzTndAEmJlGRXkqrAItBAn@4@rz6P7nbPika//JLBi5wF7s3QDWIS0ygm/dC5pqFGvr8hh5YTlYslQWBQYdCf2I4/JPGIEscfT2IycFwaCbYVkxYZJ71oWCAZElKrz8GEQRASbEK8K5c4xB6PSc@1RppNXAdgT4wKoV7w0YFWUeAhZEzDcUjhHhGf0j6JxtR2Bo7NRiR0FlM/cgI/0ohjX5Gp47qkT11osELDLkBnZBKtfeKDakI/EAhc9vgO0su3LAUYn6aE07EVMsIDMmZcSOmfhtZ4DEgKGXIOiMeORyPixFJEqBU5yE1oElG/z3g2XvI5IJa/TiW5dixiAb6TkPUd0TAG8jTWLxnRkEKXFg4@DC2PyNPQiYEFyNIjckatkFyElCowCoiCRrY1BjxuDQmDBThCjIRoTGSNhnR8eiKB6HgLzRrHQiYsXfz9D4JFtCbJXtbh1xTFunD803Myz3awDFhAZyDecShbCml@IZHe6VD4zcyePgwXAvQqAFdcogfjWLfUMSCoxoCgbmERS@p1URu7awOTxh1ZrCkUh@qDNMgLn7wpMMrsSRhSwGPFVOsKiHYDfwj8BGLDiY/88MmeASKwA78fFQi9Bq4FPpdRMGUcvhg5ILQIRWL1gEGWjbznk4ExFKYD6F7C0XTcKHAnDA5aRjEqIHAFmmKPLwbkDRlYjotNoB674liHNJq4MbaZ@H2UvOf4tK@RFA076COQF1zDcBZ0yj7A/PHWZh1DCoBBEAEjFav@9oc/9YdD6OfItoOwn6jrG9IP7IkHCFsMWQtUERU28C2XoQVwBRydN4cBri3X6VsxDu/fJEMwJNio02Di9kkAA4ZTB6bWyLqG6TgYUDumXMmDSQw4FohnXXFb4XDNBcI9qweCZQOwsRnZKjl8BlKyKVcZ1ZvEgwpRx8dEivT38kFNPtjpUMBN0ZRcVteHddA3Lcc@wZv0kOK8OVrJE7XnwglwHrnj0QSsBtT40RjsSYjMtC0gJ0KzEoP9K5AeYzSzRaDqbJJOqRRS0oOZnRLGdITrALZXceYmPaxkmsLdVjHaX9Mw0E5QsjjaMBNuMIWBGW5oREGnfRzcGlowVJwQdMQJ4iOyL7dJu/JB07G3HiUVteeAdFAPwNgkwlijEcBLRQ4DvXHprU0Kz7qBXmxupFeSJM4AhOyB3oY3xKY4GWBWUG7pcJAJU4zIAT0KBsRQi@XyI8KPQ/1IfQfW45P@oIyR@DtiPiIDOiWu5Q8n1hAUOfChiWXbdBwnMwgoiWKYI3cNIfuoJlZdi0ZC9vDu2My6JfZ@bQy0Plx6iY22UO2BUR6wWnVhlhMrHLKZSPpOCPPFvbk7OgBc3xlc/IAgtxD4IN6DQuqaQMnojNqTGKYbKPJ05Ngj0F3EzucTllvHu8PDp/XRweSog@XQiIzZeloUNH35CdG4twsVJbrZD1h97Kp16wMT/vqHh3u2Im9Lx8ESRbBQa1813dJA9xKmgT8/x1gCzF/qvNnMWgYYS34Cg39AxxTSnycgMNBnZ@gjiOUvHf@aZXQiXwJX4UQOcB1dOOr6xYtT9AdvKY9igO/cl60b8wBiGmieuGisSIUgUHsUENUnUoKDLDKP@hHQ0qPQZgV1LYwQFQ34JCO/WFXa0Uceo911qKS1CceGlAqkLYrdAvgwNwIV8ieuCy8Tn00xmSpz0DWbRpEGEwZ4q2E8AtiJeaosbgPGozCYErpQ6tK24b5RIM8mPWf2/1AiNuLF70DVmhjYp6@RwwZgKghRTFi3AcF49yzw0M6Tt4xixPf7EHzDAPyBML6JR2DpVJuIVjMYU0DpliWRAE8I0mWlzkI6SdI@Bo4vz6WdnR2pJrWkApQOoNTA0gGW8lA6YCWVlRBOwxJrUWAlrG2zFvitKy3aac8zpYuinWHc@skZy1a7Vit1C1bbTJ5FfCrgTMB3ALSKD@hHUppNLCqK2JoCoVpvIHDyL0A4P0LIR3500BMPIEBcpQ7CcrCOIHJmlG7bUnFVU@TR6rXuAfu08c32KEJc74o1gADuKkAdXZUuDc0s3@oC8p7NlgMnGrHbLdANtDZrWOvI6w3YbQtALQkDIKbALAn5wkwZRiJBAJo/ZWBe4AccFeCX41v6K/bQwHtsw@e2kb6FTI/CnB9Svef4WH4ETK1WGOSg13PuAwW@IOrpcwtYOOltYxuEZ6MNP05uMT6ehLFL@8nzr7/vgwA2xTOybiII6K@WhUvgG4pKHdwrraQpvrDbdsl@nLiQ7j3Sh21hEG@5y8L2vmrkFQX1B8n6LMsDTF2gDSMcMHWb@g1Tw530afrc3inj4e1wgLf2HY9JDp4Y2zDLc0/zO8EMb49JT@gGVl/niahDV6LkTKczaxj4N/qaV9PC3lfgmMYbZJV5xqNJPOF3TDYfE5ozxt9DkzGBNMpWz6R6EFk95x4OIhJ79yktnwtoptWBa13x4iUWt5PKiQmdIWS26fM@MIj2ICAfWzbVp@xxr/3wJ9GYCZOVHugvdPn9PhDHt8Gz@qvCfYBApstu36JyTBFsmAeIKi72qGsscu4w1bV6N@jKRt@uPzjgMJ8nKtiOpp3PGyWiBqtcbLWsNB7f3962k/bV6vbWfAWKdWAHkDbTx/wROBXHs1y12F8r3mtfU9e/Km0zP9a1BUGBa0WgIHHCZnoNYmG3h5QW/YQ9ca1wVXpAZVfopCn3fVnbqs3YsQPXSTQzfdkygI9h3t2QaNUNriuy26opviUm8zlEPeh4vzxoNwM7xmTpHtX5CovE8xTMBNd0QQvuY5cdTPF374QdBdeU37e7oE9bsfoKi6O6TBkg1t5s3rcf01BcB2K37ZbwaitWse1u/V4jL4MghEQ1IkXNeFA8W9U4ctwgIufs/hAvIEWPIn7frsDrbHMsX7VHfFoty9ubbUWKeTRyxO73CNdyh4G7VxnqFtzu1YBJOEDDnjy/1qgtjZJpPmqUluFL4JvJ815rfgV/jykHLoCA@XYwjlkWtyvKvRYsifjvJxDCfFzw2k7ciVFZalYY0QdVqkaOQns0tW4ehHrMc9zH5tRz1HCxngXC/7Nhdh8epv91Vmqj2/2Hu70l3iuXgplm9w2hkqJhfmML0zC@3mYN3Amd0K025LT3kYLifHVQ/CBSRkJGjXy6ch/s86vQRi@Obw/aHMt1YJ4/GsPUyBkE0WfBIwnA0J@Mb8lyPXuY@K8emRPPgqD/7Zq6tDqVx0OhGjmn8SNYHHsBJKeBByGB/xWSTUJ1tq3I77cky74gOFtFeMW2ipZrt1Eh2eOCb06Y7GhEy23DzAvfDilbyU3XpkgG15cnHgREcRBqhMHJspXPK4rAG6GDHfoAlkKxjRtcO@d7QhGBSCdmsM6AtNskO5/VjJq5IE0i1kTS7fJe2Sru8WzMdlxe8abtrNVtZiVVlbJSx68RQ2Kg1AV7txXUugU3cNiD47kinfiWx5brsZxSWud7AhCG4EbQyPL7kAK@9h227GYHIV/Z5tsnF5hf/@XP/WR/bEiBSM@JQLmHPu7pBh4dBdMDPm4y@tF4bOH@GvYBWYfLF@bUZ0ckmjqxPeLbYhAlvT65qCR7GslOM7ycYe63hgUXKlQNAAcr5kLj2PQDypUoGXjZKiUKQs@J55Op049HkQYxhW9TtmeSruMDJiGC@XEYoBIWyAvSp5gCsXXFjxOQrRsEV2w5EzH5y5/5Tg5UOqhCWE6HZ1uLayMSMAUm2z6x7WACWKedfKJhkIDIyGQIoCfAkRuYApR/V4g9stgWE2iimm6w4DB8k@XZ0TlRj4mEW@O431J3BnL26NWv37SNbvML8XT619/ruMTL@CZ@p@6bkVggKUh9gXq1Xm1A9apWImJ2JiZk4SYs23NcKhWfTUTGMhNXumHisf1bpnd0yjZM2K6Yj/kBboz6EcwPeFVY13zSNLPyxHU8JybqeUzKeH4ADIkFJb7jS3BHHhf/sUl2Rj6TEeqKahOzbMAbZ4iL@01e8/t0daq0voqoP6e9Ccu4r4tasdRk5GQvm40WK4W0H@COZPt9Z9rVo5Qrnc7sO6M4A7YFIYA/1XHmHP/0fJ7VWsbnzxGEGKK4kOpslRend3Z@9uLs@Pzi6OL1ObBxwanMnAShZ61MBCrB2IXYbxS4bIsX@BE6NHrcbDxhdkN4kgDKMslapAEel4CFerI0LAlbRVXM8iKvY5ZkWXenMjEfA4ckpo6cMWkngpWidTNXSBUAmQdzcgJ2NUUeFGe@xVwxckTSBIJUIIiBLxFevm0j7HYtg@cMP8B3YHpCxjoUI3UFtR0IaeXACd4chiO5lYjF/xLmY/Ajj2OOUI9hDsDCY6OvDXxy9OLH16@ON8deGzaB2QBZasjaqZrjGcTsYAcHTMNx5zbVmyDZeU8NA9j9Ed8OstyVaYuWOzuoSQM0zC7MbZwUbN0rwslN0I5o5MiNwJD2@2AZejcxGhawqHwzZ7mjI2aAAdrSzxWIKCBs1NzcgQXDMYXoxv7AG2cZHOs52naIoUP1v/3hT/zgQieG8j8m5QGU/5mX3@vIoM2dbo7jkjXIljcvzkgE3ooT7lmzNZrQYaBDcnyIjB0POHjNGILgHNkVvat@5PYb4CcIAZiJlg@NHRuPhl15FMfjmq6jf4cUdaCxpXA6AzmArdQgqdN/nuA5ErDP@l55b9fUAUn1Ou2QbU8OcXmWd6goNVAh4doZNz/0bNJoNIgY2ZZLm3t1zkg9a70viR@WiGYBVuChQJtAG2iyagF1raSZnLXypoJNcRZKpkS6dfDyXC7gKGRWABAFP/sJP0TwREHCKtzppLOYGdWbNMSB@MIPiId8YqeJ0o5U6Ij3rYjChu6ulmFx@2lNm7V1MYhvEewcwWriNtUhoCH/vkVzfCj/Ey@3O4b6pbvtJMxSd442D7zId4@rIC3k8NwPcFn@BHAlclEvlnRzT1mbJ2LSFWCLs@IzdAnzAOaVTZ2PwTg6enb84ofTs/ONAxsMUroLJhGp1ch3VK3Q7i4L0h2dT1n6/Yl@/vL7k5SR61glVXex2tb5XcTuGewtX/DeHIpVbAxkGl/bMdudVU9YAriFkGWtvgb4jK/ObYwqK/NFu9todfzMxvCft52mymg5PEAFpU7EzlJJZIuBeZEu418EV6AeDxwTUWOEcD6tHxhJNwHwNEaxpffptY7HBwRttT0gZuXGLWwVfqSF8yAdHuxE8iULCXiLrMayhY2l1nVEeO4ZLDG51XLJbKT5lGd27ESY5UNQHzo2h46YceX5Hzu@BBnAi3iVNEAiggsMLDe6YXkATPPl0mXfYavaVniTULCsOaeeo16k@OCkX@3RgxEKwhjSj2jkOr261WzPyHIH@6Htey0au04s4775TMP8CqiRFSTAbLgUt90b1W6yx0/Srfg8280/mwC/zoIxWeW0z2laegVpDXk@gc5BAyj5YeIB3IA9XlG08JT8FKjQGPgopUi0YRQ5oUHz@mUYXRvRWd8ZgpeQlQIYlO9Mc3UOwFLykItKYEM5q36Na7LrjPmmswtrHLPalub4fTqTpamk1LrIHfguTd9eS4q4oQPsAEVymqJ/9yRFOvetOJmEy1MI6xMnDVhg8GQfE5wInm/FkyuQKDig04e/pb4PKiMD2h4oCLEmQGeoFNLD1oXlkbg1u/CbZFv0rpc4luZuAL4wq9dZSlJfgEP40CGduDPo@OgV6jf6r3RNr8/lrNu80cGRKy05O2qa@VIun8/6OTnroyt7@hQzmUUWPOWlJmriDIDUrKvUgZ/gWZtZv561GnK23yzmWAt4zeeVOTT4EunaPGst9OxTcEwF@BJy7ZCzkYLiMDTNXAB@KKGsXvCs8VwWiTjDk4U4fNbJ5xEHLXuJCHzRO@d5ZqY65zrLnepJgKQPvVSNbynDL79kzD2I1Q/2SnJwUCzt5DIkcyjquc7zd@@eXdeltjUoaj93z67Ozn6ndGQp8@xUNHfFOsnpQkbPGZ/3df3Dhw8QOpB2S2tpXaWtSt223Nrfz9ULe5Vc4bBgSoV6hrimYZqKXCwq551dv@44zjjq9@EXjPDoETjPGormCVyyeSZJ5ZJ0/h6PzBzswD/2B9fyFe877EvymYFsXjsKkX@eCZnWE9Cl0t7O4RNAlebZVasdEiHzRcjcCJkPjQ9CBiKkTKvVXSzyjXajobVas5babbWFzFzIzBZCpigia3JCpjlrvGJdtJ@3eF/5n4HNP8KzoXbb47Mfj4/OjwvFhpopnhw9KxTPX3@fMeGtvHrFyhK@vjo@en76@qJQ5K1@/eLN8esz@B51W4eHeU1V1UOt1QUsZt/lW/lmHMfk3WUO5sbz1uy1rjZg0B@FzCsGqXYAjY4C8J@FTDvTlg@Ku6d7p4cHRcM1rg3zyrx6GZwu/8jL01OocGbGxyA0RsbI7JumOTPoa@PGuJkZXnBq9qFI4Z/hQdExBjNjaPiGb5rrHT3w550GL08D6CqAZvHMiLFXYwDP4enpS@hsAAN/hH@OYSCCM@Ma/gzXZNf7S8irjE5HaIOadst74@Lez21md8rVbpvOnLgrkoLUaUvdekaPOh2dK7pYBC3F6sXi8vL50cXR5aWO6dOskc0f5tVDuJqtfCN5HGT6LeSf1tjpCJI8ffv2Lf7eTq@nvMQKb6fkbXLBmy7uV8QgOExA366eb6dwXd/Tye0CuXXJcrvcnS8URXnSkeoSp0SWKThSWTQ7s@KAFEXmn6pgHcwS5ADyXllptfbK8L5XUVTZwNpd5b3ZaCRVRSUIRWkmBqFE5gv@T54vGjK7FPynKPgxubcUGaqVMrzN5vKsITdk/AafsNV80cIig5tDqS0rXWWx4N/gLisN3mdLAQIxA/g/@gsiSFeJlFlk0CP4ZLesQH5Bld09uZKvJv@aO0CMLJakEtAoSpbUbh/mSrn93fZBN9fNyY2cluu0urP1S5EyBPQt1ZqmmUHuCRmt/ko0i6KEWlTHVbXApZoL8X6pWpfk3N2rYlbzufxhO1et8sFyuc87CrSGvkW4MqBoRCaNVmMp/ZUiKC34zUnCXygv5qAQvA5cipyslnU6M8Ng8PVeMzvPWIs6654sxBQ60SvWvSzV2TKqOBezVtg2u@JCzM57C/S7OVNhHrO8W6/ndnl5v1IHQ2/mkhoDapIiVNDIstkEA9uOiiQBhxUgqtmjQ8cXMmOhjkuKfP1SVEWuzKRSZY0yUSRA/NADSU7JvgHxoetaIQkGgx3@HQIhyCApBALUdTEVxzxgGoRufwqx6Y6QiShc3plFJ5ROJ5MpXV7PnKhmffwI8S27/uvf/uUf4Pdn@P2RP//4n9Uy3v/2r/8hII47pLyfFkzhJWasVZOv3zv4GUohFX4DmHoTe4R7KE6M/g8CI0PQkKpisVopV6qlYqVQqVZ2y@ZeuVwwiwVzv7JfNQrg@irmXqVcNQuV3Wppd3e3CrXl6r6QoX7fGeg6@BRTFAkrQPiNJ8waeBYv0EYt8FF9OnB8@oTM5L7yJNNPP5BJhYilSseAiB9PX4KMFTJH6yiTCOJkQFw2ChOwC@WDSUXc2xdrOXiKB2IJikw1ZjIxJNAhUeqIotKudg/E/bJYA8erSk/NAyLuV8WauL8vKnWRDsuiuEeK@6L4zsFdWCLWF4ByyoolMQQsqaYR@KmqgPXjJkdHJqLcEdc0U0n@V5QkS9J@UZIUqQ6d7NwBQdqANE6ZWC2K8DGk8ST0iVFf8NH/bm348KoWxVaIKR/rHTKivaqInwGkwedZq9zL1QqmWjgUuGbumUJmIfTx1MxutY4@H6xhoyVkJRxeKgkZtRTsBplsNguRwkVLLImnWkNP3H9LZ76/g@EAOmItjSZaQkhxubmP/wWMG/RKGdEfkkhownehjtZAzCTm5wbdSod32fiSYSciyNl8uQyZHBGvvUSeWLVzdhyw3SXKl58cd14pqS0WV0N8vyDAmsX4vPp@/33l/cvXp69PTw5rlVoFTEQm@qwEZfOL/0M9UxtLpV2pBHFDM8MRNPeVTKu4r0XWTaabbGzJu/sKgTdmAIpmZoBObunjNn3gWmnL@/TaY4ETIFL5VX84dIq/evnhM2TWkkSImd37ojb4XwNuz065hGRxrywquCEYvb98f5kRMmUiFsugLHkdAlJd/10RJmK1ulfZywi/6PpDqTnULjOLAYWge@JtSy2OQuelhWuh/jK9gMLLCeSgy4lKcKZi0jZq3f7GZu@tT@z/EMI3AfFiWo0FKxzaBbZAS3J4@rPdhVmcLu7LWIvry8pyOXqp@nzbALtw6ssijIKTjTQRgKkMxAay0zTrxGlgZ/CEBCQZAa@0Rb6JRUx8GRZOV6kL6@vsDJMWtF7DZa19Ps/BFxwtTo/t9TnZvG75Cuh5uB9py0lr5Q5A2@gCjNQxpITMryEDMkx52UOBfDMZd9pDrqWkNDEUVpXJ95UoFkIuLnh1AcnOjevCb2VbmWMOWP/iPX1qvx@3vW5d8ZoxPvN5D@zWlexwkFzc9JqqWR8DsvW4nc873aan/FYeM@S9Jho5GBt7jpT5UtJ@MxFXpBQ@tX31i98tnLT9vNktTAq5d81PBatpFGbwA7YV3MLPwLyUlXLc/JT361YDfpiO3uIEmOu8Vb@9/QFNrmS3@altdZuGUnehYT5/AsQAnlHbzee7CgzuQuVmw7r79KmVd1uzuquqCkK9Lx2ctGModPNNfK/JVmN28Kk9gfY1GZ5NGMZVAHlod1sG0B/gVwcec/GtUOc4zhC9GaDnNZu5dwe5d7nmzs6n9kz1ugXO/pqxEjwiP0Pk13VEzr1bVyzGEhZxyeJ3Tu07LRcRsQDaB0wujNdacgxz76BmvJoNi/8G)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)

### Explanation

There were a few languages that we had thought couldn't be included because Python didn't allow UFT-8, but thanks to @stasoid's excellent Emotinomicon answer we have a new class of languages to add. Emoji is the first Emoticon language I looked at, but conclude that it could not be added.

Adding Emoji was the easiest addition I've ever had. I just looked at the Hello, World! example on Tio. (Apparently Tio has Hello, World! examples now. So cool.) And I changed `Hello, World!` to `95`. Done.

#### Others

The only other language that broke with this addition was Incident. The fix was putting an `a` prior to the `sss` on the next to last line, which detokenizes `as`.

Looking forward to @stasoid's next answer. Apparently he has a few saved up, and the last couple have been pretty great in my opinion.

Good Luck.

Comment: @zachary NEVER!

Comment: Well, there will never be an accepted answer, since the OP doesn't exist anymore. But eventually it'll reach the point where no more languages can be added (unless they're designed for this challenge)

Comment: I guess you could say,.. there's no _chance_ of that happening. I'll excuse myself.

Answer (score 8):

## 101. [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C), 2969 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]4O6O@|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡


set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"-' 101+-eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

I used [standalone pretty printer](https://tio.run/##tRZdb9vI8dlE/8G9jHZ15ZISPyV@iRSlXOLrB@LKiOP6EIq2ZYuSmciiIlIWXVl5LFD0HtpDH4or2qAFCvShv@p@Qf5BOiRlJ@m1fShws1@zM8vZmdnh7F6M0qv37y9HGfiwSGa301mSyQXCLaLlDKTrVTaxQVrsA58qw0j57nd/UqYuIJ4h/psdPkH86wo/VQBB4cH7VN7791QzAUjPbLGkp7dqIgXaJ4o4fPLixeMblw9GE11@HR6@Ojz8Shgynj4eEK1NXBAVjiqiemcpyvn5OTkHCHzZl0MhkPgwYL5liW7TtMVmv6nxTZfCTFM1TWC6LhwN23M3juNFOh5jS67gMhnH82mnsGoPgWmHPG@0@KNTvodQw1JWhIdp0ddKyo5cLvk@1ARgr3OO@nschZZZ6@@hqlGjhE6nDxx9w9Fbjp575xz1PI/6frjdNqRAbshy2JAaXuB5su/nvhT6AUc3HM23HNVJ4SSRo93ce1YKC574ldTGa3T1Uxw9KQwWh0/3Hx3tN3VPovqXjx439aPjL6iGM@PDtGC2iumz/UdPBsfPm3r11U9@9sv940Okp6Hf7zdkSZL6sh@iFvnnDb/RzbIMXpyJMkef@PmxInm46VOOPitXSkNUYyjg@vbAHPTvOBrQgPX0nq7O1BtVe6W9OkgGDxUOBgNkxLn6MlmqV@qVNtY0LVejY/VWvc3V62SgjRGNsKjXiMbqJFen6lyda9rHgv5HvR4kB4MERSX4WZarWSFVneA4HQwOUNgEN36JJVbVQsFcvcGqzrQSTs9UENThkAswYEPDXOjm62CxylIwnDCI8jgLCTT5YeA4Dh@6VEmHQ8VdLON5RnQM2WLFdnt29uTR80dnZxi@lOZevdFvSH2Ert/wdkOPjv3ChbJXG3I8W5@cnBTtZH2zrrASOVnDyQ5wphDLJknS3y09@TCerBFu/ouQTxH4BBgLjHCzFQRhb8i7fGUJY9HNaMaINsz1CehEGM3H4CRL0FqeB8w0BN83DZybtiAxteC2hVPN83YsXUiWhM9JsuRhs60K22w9VoJQFEEoiLveFxiyBQNn@YblHvNYQUNS8dVm6xdouW6DWMCEUNhuKxr2TPAqmb6ABsI8@aFqkkK6AJ5uKSvcBG1DYBe3kdA2md1wdqVbQ2MYafEttJHwIz4I@mJLtNpBLxRDkXmiLA79MP8YBJ4Chtx91HQ1WniPo7L7jGg64Ysoci@TeZrMInmWTKHluDwTKwDxAWzNaYiNfiA6TrWbKN7VBPwchRMEipEGDDzfezj@D5Eg@Ng2sHMw4tsNRkTFG3XrpcnZBPXMVbVc71506xs62rqleNiS@9W7wCrFM969HKURkA2pj5aBFpItqW8utoD@EzUhurxKwGi7rtiucMt2Me1r4o6jImeHIiNKR5flH4aZvogkHl0soFHdi2gazzm6@CS0G4ZhKDr2@efmvp5zbhplUFoBRCJVpIPtlAIppKnDrbLFBR70GiwVxslsNlpCMpnUKvrVKIWLKJpDGs1meJFAsspgnSxn43U8jmocxYzggINshOvDUbSKovVqtY4e4HGcdkYvX44WFbx7@8dfY/sHtm@q8Zt/OkbRv3v7@79/95e/cjj@9t3bP/zt3duvv8X251379t8bxxWm1cCw7hGNO0iWETgaGgDZVVyQEVtGDvdTtO96dXkFcQpxVtyw8QRUTi68oeuObdhOS7ebtmO3Dc00jKamNzXLthy1iZerrZm24WhNu@202u220wRNNxyLo9F8HE8UBS8rjRAokXh@OVuNIy/NxnEiX/kcHUeTeB7tQc7Gwh4d3xNgZQNp2UMVCHc9wshgIMCmyLoM0vhXEWrO1OYKk43RW9nEtEhHxJH0SAvR8rBzBiqPcUn4ISFC4IQ9Yhmkg1e7xP9Y6wGxHNIhlkUEl0g8oCUNKZoahJigW4S8wAON8Gt3i5rfu@TBJsA0LcuATZK4gr/oVmox4jAoj90ZkuqnqCKMZzxv6Twv8C4KqZGP41JwCxvRxMrCexUJ6oQqOphu3WWUrZZz5kiYUUByBHdbqfSjj3Ravuqk2WiZwV21ZQeI6ZCCjEs85hRb@caF2GlqUrPPVeFuahzdcuMY81jbAddxi7cGpmDP5@p8oRbf4qjUStoJrdfr@FZ57pMWGciesnt2@Er55hgWz5DiASDfv2d8ULhlNAXcvEt2fxezjcKWKaS08X@CjDt0USbnFvmL0F3GvC1uwmGlkPeGXs5GaQqHm3sXT1bzyyxO5p2DwtOjzlGG6kyDEIQ3v4hnG7sl@YelguhZQN9uF0fOqXVqnx4cD44HX/Y7dsfGpEbTOyExtDfzn7u0s@Bbbb6Fr50urYzTLIH6uiWno1sa0uoQWNsSAGdlytI1Oinu5Ydr@fvX9kfYf5ivb67L5x4qYn82nk5j/bOD87u6ovA8gFY330heVT3sHg@qI2bENIhA0SHp6dnpGcXEBEQ3MAQbCj6oFeUrHX9zxzFtk3L/Ag) because the one in the test driver doesn't work properly.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002881 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3057 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvbcttIer42Km@wNy2QYwAkARCUKPEsaWx549nxSrHsccokbUMgSMICAQ4AipRlunKVqhwuklQuUkklm6QqVXuRt8htnmKfYN9g8v3d4EESJXlyqApkAg30393/uf@/u31mx8OffsrQxU5C/3LghwlL3Dhhvci7cCODfXvJDmwvLpe2JYlDRWFv4njBgCVDl3nBeJKwvue7seTYCWuxcdqLQQWWYZFr9wSY1A8jRk3Y6NxnHnPGY3bm20PDYb4H2GfFCnNH4UcPreJwRJCJG40jF/eYBa7bY/HYdby@5/ARmTtL3CD2wiA2mOecs6nn@6zn@miwQsMpoDM2idc@iUENqRdKDJczvoH08i3rAiZwF4S7YzvihIdszLmwoH8a2eMxkJQy7BSIJ97IjZmXKDFz7dgjbqJJ7AY9zrPxks8hs4N1KtmFZzMb@E4i3nfsRgnIM3i/bOhGLrq0afBBZI@YOo28BCwglh6yE9eO2KvIdTWMAlG4sWOPgce1ITFYSCMkRIjBRdZoKEfHzxSITrQw7HEiZaLtV3/0nWQzo8my7@v4NWW5Lh39@im7ynaoDCzQGcQ7jlRbY80vLDY7HRe/mXVmDqK5hF4lcMVnZjhOTFsfA0E9AYKmTUUq6RclY@yvDcwaN2SxplACqgdpsOcB@6HAKXMmUeQCjxVT7XMQ7YfBAPwEsdEkIH4EbLcIEThh0IsLzL0A18JAyCiccg6/GnoQWkwisc/AINsh3gtj4AyFOUD3Uo4uxo1Df8Lh0DJOSAHBFTSlHp/32Q@sb3s@NUE9dSWwjtx44ifUZhL0SPIjL3B7Blug4YQ9AhqFFxjORqf8A@xntGZ1HCkAQxAhJ5WqfvdX/9AbDNDPoeOEUS9V1x9YL3QmIyBsc2RtqCIpbBjYPkcLcAUaXTTHABe27/XshIYPLtMhOBJ81Gk48XssxIDR1INpDe0LmGO/7zqJK5Q8nCTAscBG9rnwFZ7QXBA@ss8gWD4AH5uTrbODJ5CS4wqV0UeTpF9h@viIKbH5Tt2vqftbHRe4aYaWy5rmoA59M3L8E96U@xTnh8OVPEl7Xnkh2ZE/Hk7gNVATxGP4k4iY6dggJya3ksD/FdgZZzT3RVB1bqRTV4lcdgbLXhDGdUToALXXyXLTHlYyXcBdVzG3t6Zh0E4oWRLfchN@OMXAHDdyotDpgAa3BzaGSlKCDgVBYkT@5Tpp5wE0nXo7c1lFP/MgHdIDOJtUGGs0Any7JGDQm5DemlGM7Ev04ggnvZIk8/oQ8gh6G10yxyVjgFW4wtPRIBOuGLEHPQr7rKiXyuUHhJ9E5qH@Ft7jk3mvjIn4G2I@ZH13ynw7GEzsARQ5DNDEdhx3nKQWBEriBDZy0xHyj3rq1Y14KGUPbo7NvVvq79fGIO8jpJf6aJvUHowagdW6DytndjTglsh6XgR78S9vjg6AixuDyx8I5BoCH@Q7UFhMTVAyd@Y6kwTmBkWeDj1nCN0l7AJhsMI73hwen9ZHh8vR@8uhCRmr9bgkGebyE6FxZxc6SfR2P/D61FXr2gcu/PUP9/dsx6MNHYdLFOGh1r4apm1A91KmYT4/pVgC7m8xeXPLWgYYS36Cwd/RxBS5P04gMOizNwgIxA6WE/@aZ/TiQMFU4cUeuE5TOOn6q@fHNB@8cUUUA76LuWzdmYeIadA8naKpYiEEyXWGIdMDpqQ4qDKfUT8CLTOOHF7Q18IIWTPAJ5X4xasWHX0UMdrNCZW1bsPxIZUCa8tyt4A5zI@hQsHE9/EyCbiJqa52BV1z3Dg2YDDgrUHxCLCT8642vw6YDKNwyty5Vlc2DfczBfJkcubN/h9KxCG8xB1UrYmBf/oaOdwCXAhCllPW3YLgvHsSjsjPszecYsL32whzQx/zgTS@TIbwdLrDZLsZjl2gdM2TKMATQbqq1XlIpyjGx9AL1Ctla2tLqSktpYDSPkoNKu1TKY/SPi/pvERwBpV4iwIvUW2bt6BvXWXeXvQ807ok2hnFrZ@8sWq3a7XtbsFuW@mzRE8NkwnmDkDr9EA/itZsUlHT5NYUhBpnfUmQ/wrC@R4hH/veo5m4jwBxlTpIy8E6kiyYsX3dl8qrmpKIVi/MEdhnjC83RxHyele8AQK485B0dFV6XzSs8rUukPfcbtn34iG/XQO9hdbtGt46Hp31@W0DQC0NAxBTUJZEfOGujCKRMITmTznYKAxCgQr45QW2@ZI/DMwem/C57qSvIXPmwuYHrnnmBVR@AEyvVjhk/@zMuwsUfCHUF88NYNHkbBPbEJ4Nb83j7Brjk0mU@G4vff7nn/QggNviGdqXMQL682XhPfhGotL7d0orbUov/LZZsh8nPtK9B/pwbAribX9Z2NxXjb10of6QbMCzPGDqgzaKcODqbus3TMOf9NzFc3OnnIfXwwHROvBGXHJ4UmzDPc8dzW8EM6I9JT2RH9o9UySinrsSpWC6O7MHYXBprs1qRnT2FTgu4g22yjyT4SSZiDslmw8JzRvT7z5jTCGLZfvMcs0wts@8OzhISOzepbTCFshN633fPhfF91TcTKogJvIGyGwXz7vAEO0hIB/bjmtO@eNO/xFM4jEXJi/d01/ki/tdIF7gYGYNVoW7AEGmz28/R@W4IjiwA0KVFnv0NRZ5N5jq22eXNJUNf77@0ICDfJ7p8B1NJ58vbjM9XOViq2Wl8fju9o6Ttq9WN7cWK1C8AydE2uw@NB9hUvFGtq@XemvFO/3rYupflTa5H/vCRlDg2zEUJEnZ7F5ALPx2n9LSPOFMfDtale5R2RU6i5T7rqxt1WbsOaHvpZq5eNkwQEBh3s2QaNUNrSvy26opvaUu8ymiHpp4v9zrN0MnoWTpDtX5Co8k8hTKBNd0wQjvYpcTTul3p8EOwwtX3DdPQZ82YvUVHkf3uTIg1r7dvOc8pKG0DsRvmz3h@UasEsff@L3GXoRhhEQ1ZiWjeK94Nqpx7PlhzE75/T5eIEWPY3HfrMDrbPPsQHeGwqyW5c3NNiLFZzR2yO93CNf2B6G/WxmYNm53asAk6pNjT59f69SWTsmyHnRKy/AlDKz0eac3P8e/h5SDFkDgvj2KY5bFzYpypwdLI/67CUSYTwtem4l7VqwsNSuK3XtVqsYOI2c4tS/vhXpo5riLzYuZo0aL9TwQ/p8Ns3P/ML2v81K3ut27v9tr4j33Xbhpfr8lVFYqWj@zhVUsfr3P6vsTd@Ju9CHHZx9dKM5XB8X3IlVMyaixT@f@vX1@Fdo0i9PbvT7H9j3Y@YMxTI2dIIg@CR9IAAbBZHxNluvZwyR4@YBNPAnD3s/X1KXXqTwcCtXYqZs8gMXRKERyGo4QEgRfIdk0VOfbiuJ@TbL8y6rnj94TxBPRvf0uF3oQjCK4gLC881hH9LKRr6kjKd2P6jJVqVaRUwVuckn3u6x2k4c8C0P/50wEcJQ9j0IuBJK0D/uAaPgiy0u@k7Zc2o4L6RYgvnlRuuETL3dVM88DJ3L5Qvdi6Y5laPl9MkK8mISRwTicqtr5vKZJohHFH4MAYAsovq9FWwtiyyxmCAQTDuv1WbvNslezWrFmzVmTyTWZdbuiV77IfTQb8w2pl6JpO2t3m1lF15Ws0glqrKhwUNfHdLAR1L4G1/f4Q@C5Ip0F9ojvZlB5QWldbJkgSqN9sqEd9JAhvw48virphJFY@Be7S69o@eE/fttLtw8HLogceTFsfxDQlnc4cofhdF@Mm45@OB7btP1IfSAp88W6pf7kkMVTL3GGYtcQQeTrZ68q6ZZPuhGPlxPStzUshFBR1QcOdiKEJrDpha5Q3HTgZasFUYjMJ6OATb1eMowNhFyB4/ItpcU2BzCJCCxIopAUv8Ces55LGSJfdv04gWz9MDznq72EyX/8Vmx0odIjFaLyYni@87o2IoOntPjukuOEE2C96OSTG4UpiEpMRn4xIXuF2bniu8acoc134KCJ@mL/iYYRe1BPDk@ZfsQUOjlA21F1r69mD1/@8od2sdv8wkam@59/YtIKOOeb/I2@Z8VygS1A6nPSq/XqIqpXtQqTszM5JYv2qPmW7FKphDUxlcpcXIv9pBHf3uZ65075fhLfNAzIlmnfOIhhH3jVeNfCaJpZdeJ7Iy9h@mnCynS8An7WRklsiDM6sEB7I9QkO2Of2ZB0RXeYVS7iTTDEp@24UfPbxeLd9voiq/nUPZvwBYmLklHabnJysu@bjRYvRW4vpA3b9rvOtGvGC650OrNviqUZ2BZGAH9skuUc/frpVdZoFT9/jhGByfJcqfNFcDLv7NXJ85Oj01eHr16fgo1zQWXmWRiN7JWLICUY@wiNh6HPd8DBj8hz44fdxiPuN6RHKaCqsqzNGghIGDzUo6VjSdkq63JWFEUd9yTLuhuVqfvoeyx1deyESzsVrBKvu7nCQgGIebDJCfzqAnkoztUGd8XJkVkTBOkgiIMvEV6@bSLsei2HFwzfp3cwPSVjHYqTuoLaDES0CuAUbwEjkNxIxPx/CfMx5pGHMSeohzAHsPTQ6GsDPzt8/v3rl0e3x14bNoW5BbLUkLVDR0czzNTwg32u4bSxvdCbMD2YsHAM8PtDsVtm@yvXFi83vkiT@uSYfdg2GQVfFozJuBn5EYMd@jEcaa8Hz3B2mZBjgUcVe13LDS85AwYYy3muwGSJYOPm7Q1qOI4pIg3ng2ic5XC853jTGY@Oa/7ur/5BnOvoJCj/WVruo/yXovzOJAbdPgggcFyyhtjyw/MTFmO2EoSP7NkaTTRh0ITkBUgcvBE4eMEZQuAC2RW9q37U9g/gJ4QAZpLnI2fHx3OjrjpMknHNNGl@RwbfN/hOgTuDHOArDeS85o8TOmYD/2zulnd3LBNI6heLDvnu7YBWr0WHmlaDCkkX3rj54cxhjUaDyTECTre5WxeMNLP2u235wxLRLGAlEQq0GdqgyaoF6lppMzVr5y2NmpIVKpbCunXM8kIumChUXgCIRp@DlB8yZqIwZRVtBLuzhDvVy0WIg/giCNmI@MQPWy060tGR6FuTpVu6u1qlpt25NW021sUgvyGwUwKryZtUh0FD/nmD5gQo/7kotztF/Ut300Ghpe4c3j4PpN48zUO0sIPTIKRdi2fAlakls7RtWrvamp3IaVfAlqziM7qEHcCuHNf7GI7jwydHz787Pjm9dZ6FQyo3wRSmtBr5jm4U2t1lQbmh8wuWfvvMPH3x7bMFI9exWqUMBLHKG26iuWm0m5jeMfobsUFwe2xecWsgq/i1HfPdbP0ZT5hv976qNdcAn4jVzFujqtrVvN1ttDpB5tbwnzedPssYOTpwhlIn5mfPFLbB4zxfbHu8Cs@hL/ccq9ETgvA@rR@wWWya0OmVUsvsuRcmHbeQjNV2ipxVG9ew1cQRIMGDxfBwHOmXrCVj3NVYjnRraXodEZEYhktMrrVcMptoPhapHj9BZweI8iPPEdAx97YiIeTHvZASPE9WWQQyE1qQ4cnSJU8MYPfLpd6ex3cB7OgypWBZc@qOPP3VAh/yAqszDfBKYZQgH4mHvndWt5vtGVvu@N933MGIx76XqHTOYGZQwgVqVI0IsBq@S8cUGtVueiaCLY4u5Pnph5MJ@HUSjtkqyX3qLkovkeewpxN0Dg1w2XeTEeD6/PHSJZfvsl@HOhqDj8oCiTZGUVMajFGvjNGNoTvreQNMG6pWgIf5xrJW5yZsLY/kVIFTFaz6Ja1hrzPmZ531WOOY3bYNL@i5M1WZKlqtS9zBd2X65kLR5Fs6wA@cpKdPejdPnixs305SI1ye2rhp39Xq0q6vm021agxjiQ5jIFTHiKdJ9D2KmBDV/sgeM3USUPQSM4PxV7WjBoU4iTSmt2hymrKA5fM8yMeDVxiMt@zzkufTcUeVDrmqZhNypq9x0KPHJ2/M2pZhdFHmg2gsS/n5E8QOlNlqEiJCNKnxbjGb4q9GGE2RzhBG4pnlw0qUXEeA2ljNDXkw5AYIXnCqWesxWzmClQUKrlartVQa171blUEtbk8sholuN3itRfgI/qab7uAaHcamY1ZI2zw4lINfuUEAe1WhMyNYJ7MnULJIKyz@Z0BheX5zDcE/TPfwb87ZR8qVHyIyyZp1niDW55ieP3RYJ@n0OwHN0fVL8xemYdav1KzfvDQRVmktNTtsWvntXD6fDXJqNqDA4vFjyivnWcQt7w3ZkGcA0rO@VocyI85pZoN61m6o2V6zlOMt8JrPa1do8CU2jausPTezjxEmFPAlEqapZmONbKFoGNYc@JF5ZM0CFOZKlZk8o2OwNHzWy@cJByP7nhD4YnZO83yO6JyaPJOtp@GqORgtfMg1mfz0U8baRea0v7uthvul7a1chmUOZDPXefr27ZOLutK2@yXjx@7J@cnJH2sdVck8OZatHbnOcqaUMXPFz3um@eHDBwRyrN0yWkZXa@tKt6229vZy9cJuJVc4KFhKoZ5hvlW0LE0tlbTTzk5Q9zxvHPd6@IVDOieHUKZGonmES7VOFKW8rZy@o/Nd@1v44/9wLV/pvsW/pJ85yO1rS2PqjzMp03oEXdre3Tp4BFTdPL9qtQMmZb5ImUsp86HxQcogXs20Wt35PK@3jTxsLq/nG@1Gw2i1Zi2922pLmSspM5tLmZJMTMpJmeas8ZJ31n7aEr3mfwTDv8ezoXfb45Pvjw5Pjwqlhp4pPTt8Uiidvv42Y@GtvHqlym16fXl0@PT49atCSbT65fMfjl6f4HvcbR0c5A1d1w@MVhdYzL7Jt/LNJEnY2/c5WMnT1uy1qTcw6PdS5iWH1DtAo6MBfud49/jgs5RpZ9rqfmm/VPSLF0Xr3Dp/ER4v/7EXx8eo8GbFj2FUHBaHVs@yrFnRfV28LF7OiqPw2Oqh6OKvOELRK/ZnxUExKAaWtd7RPf9Gx@GL4xBdhWiWzIoJ9Vrs4zk4Pn6BzvoY@CP@vGKREJwVL/Cv6Fv8evce@W6x05HaUNhueXdc2v2xzd1/udptuzMv6cqsoHTa1WpV6dYzZtzpmELr5RJUliDm8/fvnx6@Onz/3qTMdtbI5g/y@gGuZivfSB/7mV6LWGg0tjqSok7fvHlDvzfTi6ko8cKbKXuTXngz5b2KHIYHKeib1fPNFNfFHZ1cL7Brl6q2y92ruaZpjzpKXRGUqKqLkEaVrc6s1GclmUcKVbgKa5tmo92y1mrtlvG@W9F0tUi1O9o7q9FIq0paGMnKTA4jhV3NxZ96NW@o/NLoT9PoY3pvaSqqtTLeZlfqrKE2VPqGT9Tqat6iIoe7Qqmtal1tPhffcFe1huizpYFASs7@j/6FMYvHTMnMMzQ9BGynrCH1c7WdXbWSr6Z/zS0Qo8rbyjZolBVbabcPctu5vZ32fjfXzamNnJHrtLqz9UtTMgwqt9CappUh7kkZo/5StkqyQlpUpwXP0HcNH6nYdrWuqDlxsdzyqljVfC5/0M5Vq2K0XO7zlobm6FzGlYGmMZU1Wo2l@FeaoLXwu2Ipg1GeX0EjRB0mGDVdyex0ZsUih6@fNbNXGXte592zubyAThWLd68qdb7ELV/JWTtqW115LmevzuY0C@csjc@f5Z16PbcjynuVOty@lUtriqhJi6hwY9vhFgZPT5qkgMUaiGqeuQMvkDLja6qdL5fLZgn32Te7R6WZVKelYLHuLOuy0HRWqfIOMyyOqxICvTMIesr2igjkfd@OWNjvb4nviFiR@7sIGlzfp0UUCugQ1/i9KZKILSkDj4BwBtW4Rie2O3Hd6WQydZfXEy@u2R8/Ih/h1@9/83d/it9v8fsb8fybf6@W6f773/z1v/3un/5FwvMvfv@bv/3X3//mL/8ev39Mf39/8ydJRNoWK@8tCpb0ghYoqpbYrvHoM0qRW5X@EPSNJs6Q9um8hGZYxL1FySBulErVSrlS3S5VCpVqZads7ZbLBatUsPYqe9ViAZNrxdqtlKtWobJT3d7Z2akWmFUqV/ekjBv0vL5pYrKyZJnxAtIrOnHZoLOpoTFsSZme20dw@YjN1J72KNNbfGCTCpO3K50iEjoe/6pMY1fkdVUWIw0C5mqxMIGzKe9PKvLunlzL4Snvy9socmHPVFZUoJey0pFlrV3t7st7ZbmGqV1XHlv7TN6rIjDe25O1uqwrDJTkdXdQluVdVtqT5bceHU5gcn0OzBcsWdLE4KYNg@Gn6xLVj5sCLVWuqoyLvdqRhVEIDVNURdkrKYqm1NHJlryul1qdaASJgsIFijJwAopVuNt65CaTKFCrOjwK06tafS5Q@oM1nKJzBON2RAExHxLZ8G5Vps8AaahVGqpVPsvVCpZeOJCEuu9aUmYu9eiE2U6V1at1ijXgghstKasQWsq2lNG3w50wk81mEau8asnb8rHRMNOwo2XymKNDYQgFAMYinmkxU4pc2oDo0f@ZFPNIpUy0DFicyf83LwMjNNGnVCf/JWdSj3lJM2FHINT4kuHHj9jJ1XJRO/3/GLUXxGm7dsrP3ra7TPvya8@/qmzrLZ4XIDmcM/B2Pj6tvtt7V3n34vXx6@NnB7VKrQKnlok/a2HZ@hJ8V8/Uxsr2jrKNaKeZEcRZe1qmVdozYvsy0023SdWdPY3hjbuskpXp07y8nJZvT9trpQ3v04sRD/eASOUXvcHAK/3ixYfPWdNUFMas7O4XvSH@NXB7cixErMq7ZVmj7eX43ft37zNwTEwulaGCeRMBtWn@cQlmXq3uVnYz0k@med@6DmqXmVHfRdIwGW1KjQ4j74VNaWOwTI9QeDH55EZLL8DIDVDGT35g/VvqGtY@8f@wi28S4cVthQp2NHAKfLmf5eiodbsLH7HYKlKplnYrtOXmhrAhVqyLTSjqwqsvixiFTBhJalF8pExI9ZpWnXkN6gxPJFDpCHQtWuSbVKRVE46F19Xq0vquDcekhdZruKy1z@cF@FygJehxRj1BtqhbvgK9Ee1uO2raWrsB0C52KRvvFJWUzK8hA1m0uuyhwH42GTfaI1fUFjRxFFaV6feVKOZSLimM6hKRnRvXpV@pjnZFOWz9y@jxY@fduD3q1rVRM6FnPj@C4ztXPQGSS5qjpm7Vx0C2nrTzea/bHGm/Uscc@VGzCGCMTT3H2tVS0kEzFVesFT61A/1L0C08awd5q1uYFHJvm58KdrNYmOEHthX8wo9g3oKVatL8lA/qdgM/SqevcQKTQN6uX99MQ5Nz1W9@atvdZlGr@2iYzz8DMcAzbvv5fFfD4D4qbzes@48f23m/Nav7uq4R1Lvt/WftBIVuvknvNdVuzPY/tSdoX1PxbGIYXwPyaHddBugP@NXBYyG@FeoCxxmhNwN6o2Yz93Y/9zbX3Nr61J7po25BsL9WXAmekJ8R8us6ouberisWZwmPEVX5G6/2jZGLmVyA9oHJhfFaS4Fh7i1qxitrmP8X)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c)

### Explanation

Last versions of gcc support traditional mode only in preprocessor (no ‑traditional, only [‑traditional‑cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html)), but it is enough for us.
All the stuff that separates C89 and K&R C from other languages and from each other (preprocessor directives, comments, trigraphs) is handled by preprocessor.

Trigraphs were introduced in C89, so we can distinguish C89 from K&R C by `'??-'&1` (see also [C++17 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127570)):

```c
puts('??-'&1 ? "101" : "92");
```

Only Incident broke, fixed as usual.

#### Japt

In Japt link version 1.3.0 was specified, but the actual version that gets loaded is 1.4, see browser F12, Elements, head -> script.
To avoid further confusion, I changed the version to 1.4.

Answer (score 8):

## 103. [Unicat](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unicat), 3072 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]4O6O@|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"-' 101+-eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

The code above is generated by [this pretty printer](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOoSA/pzI9J79ED8TgKkgtylHQzS0tSbNQ0C1wVVAv1o9J1X80YbZ@urUCkF0CZHdC2WlAdg@EHaevAAT66go2qOb9/w8A).

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002811 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3161 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tXtfc9vIlt@zUfkG96UFcgyAJACCEiX@lzS2fK/njkdayx5vmaRlkARJWCDAAUCRskzXfUpVkn3YbKW2NruVTDZVqboPecpTUrlVW7X7up9iPsF8g9nf6Qb/SKIkz1YCCkCj@3T36fOvz@ludexo@MsvKbrYSeBdDrwgZrETxawXuhdOaLCvL9mB7UbFwrYkcagw6E26rj9g8dBhrj@exKzvek4kde2YNdg4acWgBEux0LF7AkzqByGjKmx07jGXdcdj1vHsodFlngvYZ/kSc0bBBxe1omBEkLETjkMHz4j5jtNj0djpun23y3tkzix2/MgN/MhgbvecTV3PYz3HQ4UVGt0cGmOTaC1LdGpIvUBiuLrjG0gvv9IOYHxnMXBnbId84AEbcyosxj8N7fEYSEopdgrEY3fkRMyNlYg5duQSNVElcvwep9l4SeeA2f76KNmFazMb@E5C3nbkhDGGZ/B22dAJHTRpU@eD0B4xdRq6MUhAJD1kJ44dsleh42joBaxwoq49Bh7XukRnAfUQ00AMzrJaTTk6fqaAdaKGYY9jKRVuv/qzbySbGXWWPqvirstyVTr67im7SrcoDSzQGNg7DlVbY/XPLDJbLQf3zOqYg3AuoVUJVPGYGYxj09bHQFCPgaBpU5JS@kXBGHtrHbPaDV6sCZSA6oEb7LnPvs/xkXUnYegAjxVR7XMM2gv8AeiJwYYTn@jhs908WNAN/F6UY84FqBb4gkfBlFP41dAF0yJiid0Bgewu0V4oAyco1AGyl1B00W8UeBMOh5pRTAIIqqAqtfi8z75nfdv1qArKqSmBdehEEy@mOhO/R5wfub7TM9gCjW7QI6BRcIHubDTKM6A/ozWt40gBGIwI@FCp6Ke//LveYIB2DrvdIOwl4vo96wXdyQgI2xxZG6JIAhv4tsfRAlyOehfV0cGF7bk9O6bu/cukC44E73UaTLweC9BhOHWhWkP7AurY7zvd2BFCHkxi4JhjI/tc2ApXSC4GPrI7YCzvgPfNh62zgyfgUtcRIqOPJnG/xPTxEVMi8526X1H3t1oOcNMMLZM2zUEV8mZkeBa@lPsE5/vDFT9Jel65AemRNx5OYDVQ4kdj2JOQiNm1MZyIzEoM@5djHU5obosg6lxJp44SOqwDzV4MjMuIkAGqr5PmJi2seLqAuy5iTm9NwiCdELI4umUmvGCKjjluZEQh0z51bg9sdBUnAzoUAxI98pzrQzv3IenUWsdhJb3jgjskBzA2CTPWxgjw7YKAQWuCe2tKMbIv0UpXGOkVJ5nbB5NHkNvwknUdUgZohSMsHXUy4YIRuZCjoM/yeqFYfID5cWge6m9hPT6a9/KYBn@DzYes70yZZ/uDiT2AIAc@qtjdrjOOEw3CSKIYOnLTEPJMPbHqRjSU0gc3@@bWLbH3a32Q9RHcS2y0TWIPQo1Aat2DljM7HHBNZD03hL54lzd7B8DFjc7l9wRyDYH38h0oLKYmCJkzc7qTGOoGQZ4O3e4QskvY@UJhhXW82T2y1nuHydH7y64JGavxuCAZ5jKL0LizCZ04ersdWH1qqnEtgzN/PeP@lu1otKHhYIkiLNRarmHaBmQvIRrm81PyJWD@FpM316ylg7GkJwgMVYeaQliGcTyOKjA3bjycdAyw1XwVXj6Pj33irBmHl24ciHTHCzrmyI6gTOaiB7M76bizGyPieUuCf4ikC0zj/YjVYf9/mEBEVKUfKVqV5z8h4LUimU@tvAnxlAHIgQxQSu1HBrlfz2ABTi/9riobXO4NaIicYzJpmawhQbWWdHkSjMhksDd8eiF/4esQZqYP0yKNL@Mh6KB3mWzXg7Hjq8o1oVQ03qGqVbl3oCjGh8D11Stla2tLqSgNJYfUPlI1Su1TKovUPk/pPEVwBqV4jRxPUWmT16C8tjJvLlqeaW1i24xcoI/uWLWblcp2O2c3reRdoLcGuwQzBGidXmhH0ep1Smqa3JhioEanL0b/UlC2x6XhpeMPJGc2DsKYfXf89Ojs5PDV7@qyOYlC03M7po8J8WwEdYP7K4v6r6D738L5YN@6NCf04aqsnFhpiWtLkgUtt69rtbwqKQi/6QJSBAs1vtw8n8nrTfEKcCXOAxLfVeosb1jFa03AA79ds@9GQ/64BnoLrdslvHY06vT5YwNAJZmQMLuRv050@Ya8PZoTgwC@/ZSDjQI/EKiAXq5vmy/5y4Ad24TPdXNxDZmO05/AAzQ7rk/pB8D0colD9jsd9y5Q0IVQX7w3gIWTziaywXoMb80o7Brh40kYe04vef/zH3pgwG32DO3LCK7l@TJxBroRq/T@ndxKqtIHf2zm7IeJh8DjgTa6NrmTtrdMbG6LdILp@tAOwc3LBTchjfSAfXtI3qEq3qTnLN6bO@E0vT5Ridq@O@KcxJtmXW7I7qh@Y5oV9ckdD73A7pkiRHKdFWsFE5yZPcDAzLWwzQg7X4DjYiZkq5gIs0g8EU8Kgx5iojum@z7lTCDzRbtjOWYQ2R33DgoSErt3CbHQDbL6et@zz0XyjJKbhyoGE7oDxFyL911g8EPgKo7trmNO@etOe@JPojFnJk/d017oieddIK7fhcfprxJ3AWKYHn/8GpHjgtCFXhCqtAyhr5HIvUFUz@5c0sw4/PXyQx0Oslmmw5bUu9lsfpvpwSpKWC14jMd31@92k/rl8ubaYm2EN9ANENA5D@krJhl3ZHt6obeWvNPeLjyJVWqTObIvbPgYnh1BQOKEzM4F2MIf9wktzRvdiWeHq9Q9IrtCZxEM3hVPrOqM3W7guYlkLj7usoM3nbtVM7TixR@rqvSVzJZP4UTRRPyZZkifr9vA4nuecENfPT/mcEE3Jjf@DtH5AoskPGiKUdZkwQjuIlc3mNJ9p8IOgwtHPDdPSR83YvUFFkf3uDDALb9dvdd9SEJphYI/NlvC841YxV1vY36FvQiCECFUxApG/l72bBTjyPWCiJ3y5320QPAYReK5WYDXyebavt4dCrVapjdX24gUn9HYIX/ewVzbGwTebmlg2njcKQGTsE@GPXl/qVFbGiXLetAoLd2ZwLeS953W/Bx/DwkHheYw3y75NcvkZkG504IlAcTdA4TbT0sxmwf3LF9aSlYYOfeKVIUdht3h1L68F@qhmeMuMi9mjvEl94rhxVGFcgmJOBSe8r9inrJ27u@t92XG6lazew8NYo3L554Da82ft3jLCnnrV9aw8vkvN119b@JMnI2m5LjzwYH83MfLL0cqnwyjwj6ee/e2@UVo02ROX/eaHttzoe4PujIVdgJf@oTC4vvwGviT8TVerjXwcuK/vJ9Qw/FCo4PeNZSo5NdaotLD7lGFnTrxA9p6NAoQwAYjuAn@F7A5cd/5Jph4XmMzz1m1/MF9Ah8jvLfd5foQHFQ4HOCcex7p8Gg2EjkxLoX7UV2GL@Uy4izfiS/peReJN1nNThB4v4YlMJ49l9wwOJe0a/gFrLkcdeCZdVdrV19A/kUICGJRuBtvnAbEKhHfVFqu8ka5ZDcMeW6Y7H1Eyw3G1HO/Gzp8zXexrMhStBI9GcFBjYPQYBxOVe1sVtMkUYkcnoEPsAUU3@KhVXaxexQxeJ4xh3X7rNlk6atZJV@x5qzO5IrM2m3RKl/vPZqN@d7MS1G1mbbb9bSi60paafkVllc4qONh/tkIal@D67v8JfBcDZ359ogv7FN6MdKq2D2AW0hbRkPb7yEkfw0ac/84CMUauNhoeUXrH//0x16ykzZwMMiRG8HKDHza/Q1GzjCY7ot@k94Px2ObduKoDUSBnlh@158csmjqxt2h2ECD1/r62atSsvuR7Enj44SEeQ0LwVQU9YGDHQumCWx6gSMkKOl4WWsxKIQCk5HPpm4vHkYGfDy/6/DdlcWKPzAJCcyPw4AkMMees55DIWmPEPswAW@9IDjna4@EyT/9Uez5oNAlEaL0onu@CbnWI4NNtvhGS7cbTID1opGPThgkICoRGQHNhIwB5N8R@RrrDm2@GQVJ1BdbMdSN2I55cnjK9COm0CY6rRlX3b6aPnz52@@b@Xb9MxuZzj//wdSuErrJX@l7ViTn2AKkOie5Wi/Oo3hVqjA5PZOTYdF2Ld@dXAqV0CamUpqza7G1MuI7vVzunCnfWuH7Zz4ZCtpC9SPoBz413rRQmnpanXjuyI2ZfhqzIp00gBG3kRJ7w4z27mmbgKqkZ@wTG5Ks6F1mFfP4EgTxaGdqVP96sXq4vb7Kaz51OhO@AnJRMArbdT6c9Fm91uCp0OkFtHfZfNeats1oQZVWa/ZVvjAD2YIQ4I9N0pyj755epY1G/tOnCC6fLM@VqtMdBly901cnz0@OTl8dvnp9CjLOxShTz4JwZK9MBAnB2IMvPgw8vhkMeoSuEz1sNh5xuyE9SgBVlaVtVoPrw2ChHi0NS0JWWZfTIinKuCVZlt0oTMxH32WJqWMnnNsJY5Vo3czlFgJAxINOTmBXF8hDcK42mCs@HJnVMSAdA@LgS4SXX5sGdr2UwwuC79M3iJ4MYx2KD3UFtRmIxiqAE7wFjEBy4yDm/48wH2MeeRhzgnoIcwBLD/W@1vGzw@ffvn55dLvvtW4TmFsgSwlZO39zNIMbADvY5xJOe7wLuQmSPfqFYYDdH4qdPNtbmbaIXbiR2/EcLkl9MswedJuUgq9DRqTcjOyIwQ69CIa014Nl6FzGZFhgUQ2JkOYPpvtMToEAxnKeyzFZItiofnuvFoZjCjem@15UTnM43nK06bhDyzF/@su/E0ccWjHS/y5J95H@C5F@ZxKBbu@JCxyXpCGyfP/8hEWYrcTAR/ZsbUw0YdCE5PoIUdwRKHjBCULgAtnVeFftqM3vQU8wAcQky0fGjvfnhG2VNkkrpknz@yDw@gbfqnBm4ANsJd8z/WFCJ05gn83d4u6OZQJJ/WLRoO6KBvWxaFDTKhAh6cId1993uqxWqzE5gjfr1HergpBm2n63Lb9fIpoGrCRcgSZDHVRZ1UBZI6mmpu2spVFV0kLFUli7ille8AUThcoTANEo20/oIWMmChJSgem@M4u5Ub1cuDjwL/yAjYhO/NzRoiEdDYm2NVm6JburZXHaHlyTZmOdDfIbAjslsIq8SXQYJOS/bZAcH@l/L9LNVl7/3N50ZmYpO4e3j8aoNw@20FjYwakf0DbJM@DK1IJZ2DatXW1NT@SkKWBLWvEJTUIPoFddx/0QjKPDJ0fPvzk@Ob11tINDKjfBFKY0atmWbuSa7WVCuSHzC5J@/cw8ffH1swUh17FaxSMEsQpKbqK5qbebmN7R@xuxI3G7b15wqyMr/6UN84hGf8ZD89utr0rNNcAnYvn0Vq@qdjVvtmuNlp@61f2nTQexUkaGzl4h1Yr4MSyFbbA4zxf7LK@Cc8jLPSdM9Jgg3I/rZ00WuzR0kKPQMHvOhelPPE8yVvs3clqtXcNWE6dhBA0W3cNwJDlpS0a/q7660q218HVERNQZLDG5VnNJbBrzsQj1@GEy24eXHyLm5NARt7YiIOQnnxASPI9XUQQiEwpKebB0yQMD6P1ybbnn8m0HO7xMRrAsOXVGrv5qgQ9ZgdWZDFglOqowxNg8t1O1680ZWx45uO@4hhGNPTdW6ZzEzKCAC6NRNRqAVfMcOmZRK7eTMx1scfQiy09vnExAr5NgzFZB7lNnkXqJOIc9naBxSIDDvpmMANfnr5cOmXyHfRfoqAw6KgskmuhFTcZgjHpF9G4MnVnPHWDaULUcLMxXlrU692FrWQSnCoyqINVvadF8nTC/6qzKGsXspm24fs@ZqcpU0Sptog7ylembC0WTb8kAPzCTnJ7p3Tw5s9B9O06UcHXq5IZ@l8tLvb6uNuWyMYwkOg0CVx09nsbht0hiQlT7I3vM1Ak/ehQxg/FPtaX6uSgONaY3aHKaMp9ls9zJx4sXGIzX7POU69HJP5XOe6pmHXym3Mjv0eujO2ZNyzDaSPNONJam@PwJfAeKbDUJHiGqVHizmE3xqxBGU4QzhJF4p3m3EgXXIaA2FnNFHgy5AoIWfNSs8ZitDMFKAwVVy@VKwo3r1q3MIBa3JxbDRLMbrNbCfQR9k11@UI3OJQPqCcI2Fwbl4PeO70NfVcjMCNrJ7AmELNRyi0PyueVRxjUEf5ccGrg5Zx8pV14AzyRtVnmAWJ1jen7fYq241W/5NEdXL83fmIZZvVLTXv3ShFulNdT0sG5ltzPZbNrPqGmfHIvHjymunKfht5wZsiHPAKSnPa0KYYafU0/71bRdU9O9eiHDa@Azm9WuUOFzZBpXaXtuph/DTcghJxSqqaYjjXQhbxjWHPiReqTNHATmSpWZPKMTodR92s1mCQcjfUYIfDZbp1k@R7ROTR7JVhN31RyMFjbkGk9@@SVl7SJy2t/dVoP9wvZWJsVSB7KZaT19@/bJRVVp2v2C8UP75Pzk5M@1lqqknhzL1o5cZRlTSpmZ/Kc903z//j0cOdZsGA2jrTV1pd1UG3t7mWput5TJHeQsJVdNMc/KW5amFgraaWvHr7quO456PdzBkI43w5WpEGse4VKtE0Upbiun7@h82v4WfvwP1/KTnls8J8nmILevLY2pP8ykVOMRZGl7d@vgEVB1svyqVA6YlPospS6l1PvaeykFfzXVaLTn86zeNLLQuayerTVrNaPRmDX0dqMppa6k1GwupQoyESkjpeqz2kveWPNpQ7Sa/QEE/xbvmt5ujk@@PTo8PcoVanqq8OzwSa5w@vrrlIWv4uqTCrfp8@XR4dPj169yBVHrt8@/P3p9gvyo3Tg4yBq6rh8YjTawmH2VbWTrcRyzt2cZaMnTxuy1qdfQ6bdS6iWH1FtAo6UBfud49/jgk5RqpprqfmG/kPfyF3nr3Dp/ERwv/9iL42MUuLP8hyDMD/NDq2dZ1izvvM5f5i9n@VFwbPWQdPDLj5B08/1ZfpD3875lrTd0z9/oOHhxHKCpANXiWT6mVvN9vAfHxy/QWB8df8DPzecJwVn@An95z@LXuzPEu/lWS2pCYNvF3XFh94cmN//FcrvpzNy4LbOc0mqWy2WlXU2ZUatlCqmXCxBZgpjPz86eHr46PDszKbKd1dLZg6x@gKveyNaS136q1yASGrWtlqSo0zdv3tD9ZnoxFSmeeDNlb5ILX6a8V5KD4CABfbN6v5niurijkesJdu1S1WaxfTXXNO1RS6kqYiSq6sClUWWrNSv0WUHmnkIZpsLaptlot6g1GrtFfO@WNF3NU@mO9s6q1ZKighaEsjKTg1BhV3PxU6/mNZVfGv00jTKTZ0NTUawV8TW7Umc1taZSHrKo1tW8QUkOd4VUU9Xa2nwu8vBUtZpos6FhgBSc/X/6CyIWjZmSmqdoevDZTlFD6OdoO7tqKVtOfvUtDEaVt5VtjFFWbKXZPMhsZ/Z2mvvtTDuj1jJGptVoz9YvTUkxiNxCaupWiqgnpYzqS9kqyApJUZUWPAPPMTyEYtvlqqJmxMUyy6tklbOZ7EEzUy6L3jKZT1saqqNxGVcKksZUVmvUluxfSYLWwH3FEgIjPb@CRIgyTDBqspLZas3yeQ5f7dTTVyl7XuXNs7m8gE4EizevKlW@xC1fyWk7bFpteS6nrzpzmoUzlsbnz@JOtZrZEem9UhVm38okJXmUJEkUOJHd5RoGS0@SpIDEGgZV7zgD15dS42uinS0Wi2YBz9lXu0eFmVSlpWCx7izrspB0VirzBlMsisoSHL0OGD1le3k48p5nhyzo97dEPjxWxP4OnAbH82gRhRw6@DVeb4ogYktKwSLAnUExrtGJ7UwcZzqZTJ3l9cSNKvaHD4hH@PXzj3/zb3H/Efdfifdf/c9ykZ4///gf/8dP//Xvkfl/cf8f3P/75x//8x/Ezb//hPsf1vL@lNxrcOKW0NZ/@PnH//Tff/7xL/4W939J7r@9ef/01/9L/P1j8qPk3//013@ih/iQJKLgFivuLRKW9ILWQcqW2BVyKRup0ClLvwMZR5PukPbl3JgmcrjXeckgohcK5VKxVN4ulHKlcmmnaO0WizmrkLP2SnvlfA5zeMnaLRXLVq60U97e2dkp55hVKJb3pJTj99y@aWJOtGSZ8QSiODpJWqMzuIExbEipntOHD/uIzdSe9ijVW2SwSYnJ26VWHnEjd7NVprErMu4qixBtAXM1n5vAphX3JyV5d0@uZPCW9@VtJLlMzVSWVyD@stKSZa1Zbu/Le0W5Ag9CVx5b@0zeK8P/3tuTtaqsKwwjyerOoCjLu6ywJ8tvXTpjweTqHJgvSLIcE8NsYBgMt65LVD6uC7RUuawyLl3llix0TwiyoirKXkFRNKWKRrbkdfHXqjRGDFGMcIGiDJyAYhlWvRo68ST01bIOw8X0sladC5T@zRpO4Tl8fjskv5t3iaB7tyxTNkBqapm6ahQ7mUrO0nMHktCqXUtKzaUenZzbKbNquUouDSx9rSGlFUJL2ZZS@nawE6TS6TRcolcNeVs@Nmpm4t00TO7atMjbIT/DWLhNDWZKoUP7HD36L0UxXZWKNJYBi1LZf@VloIc62pSqZCblVGKYL2nCbQmEap9T/FgVO7larp1PfB7GV14Qpe3KKT9T3Gwz7fN3rndV2tYbPPxADDpnoO18fFp@t/eu9O7F6@PXx88OKqVKCbYzFX3SgqL12f@mmqqMle0dZRtOVT0lBmftaalGYc@I7MtUO9mNVXf2NIYvbhkLVqpP0/9y9r/tHaylNnxPL0bcqwQipd/0BgO38JsX7z@lTVNRGLPSu5/1mvir4fHkWLBYlXeLska72NG7s3dnKdg/JheKEMGsCb/dNP@8ADUvl3dLuynpF9O8b/kIpcsArO8gNpmMNkVgh6H7wqbo1F9GYUi8mHx0wqUVYGQGaGGB7MB6XmIa1rL4v8giTyK8uK5Qwg4H3RzfVWAZOkLebMNGLHakVCqlTRFtuYcidIjlq2Kvi5pwq8skeiEVRiycF5kUcKlu3aoyt0aN4Y04LemBrkWNbJ2StDjDsXDbWlVa3xzimDRQew2XtfrZrACfC7TEeLqjnhi2KFt@Ar0RbaJ31aS2dgOgmW9T0N/KK8kwv2QYCNbVZQs59quHcaM@QlJtMSaOwqowyV@xYi5l4tyoKtGwM@Oq9Hu1q11RqFz9PHr8uPtu3By1q9qoHtM7mx3B8J2rrgDJxPVRXbeqYyBbjZvZrNuuj7Tfq2OO/KieBzD6ppYj7WrJab@esCvSch@bvv7Zb@eeNf2s1c5Ncpm39Y85u57PzXCDbDkv9wOItyClGtc/Zv2qXcNNUfs1SmASyNrV63t2qHKuevWPTbtdz2tVDxWz2WcYDPCMml4229bQuYfC2xWr3uPHdtZrzKqermsE9W57/1kzRqKdrdN3RbVrs/2PzQnqV1S86@jG04A86l3nAdoDflXQWLBvhbrAcUbozYDeqF7PvN3PvM3Ut7Y@Nmf6qJ0T5K/kV4wn5GeE/LqMqJm364LFScJdUVX@yq18ZWQiJucgfSBybrxWU2CYeYuS8Uob5v8C)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)

### Explanation

Unicat is a language whose commands are represented with 9 cat emojis:

```
              UTF-8         c
  U+1F638   F0 9F 98 B8   0
  U+1F639   F0 9F 98 B9   1
  U+1F63A   F0 9F 98 BA   2
  U+1F63B   F0 9F 98 BB   3
  U+1F63C   F0 9F 98 BC   4
  U+1F63D   F0 9F 98 BD   5
  U+1F63E   F0 9F 98 BE   6
  U+1F63F   F0 9F 98 BF   7
  U+1F640   F0 9F 99 80   8
```

All other characters in the source file are ignored.
Further I will use indices instead of real emjis, they are the same as in `c` variable in Unicat source code.

Every command is represented by two cats. We will use 3 commands:

- asgnlit(31) - assign number to variable. takes 2 parameters (numbers) - variable id and a number
- echoval(44) - print variable as number, takes 1 parameter - variable id
- diepgrm(88) - exit program, no parameters

Numbers are represented in octal using cats' indices, and 88 indicates end of the number (roughly speaking; see `parseNbr` in cat.py).
For example, 103 = 147 octal = 147 88 =

So the program is:

```
31 0 88 147 88   44 0 88   88
asgnlit          echoval   diepgrm
```

I think this is the first time when nothing broke because of my addition.

Test driver updates: removed Japt wrapper, fixed Cubix wrapper. Dennis added Cood, Reng and Trefunge to TIO.

Comment: PingPong exits with exit code 216. [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/dfJ10ZpV)

Comment: I'll fix it in my next answer.

Comment: Both archways and set now on TIO.

Comment: I'll try to work on the rest of the interpreters tomorrow

Answer (score 8):

## 105. [Emoji-gramming](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji-gramming), <s>3291</s> 3267 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d1114O6O@x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ ppppppp            (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002822 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3361 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tXxfc9tIkuezEfcN5qUMsk2AJACCFCX@l9W2POOedktn2e0@k7QNkqAICwTYAChRluWYe9mdmdu425udm5jt3ZvemdiLmIi7p73YiN3YibiI29f9FP0Frr9B3y@rAP4RKcs9eweJQKIqKzMrKysr6w/Zs8LRd9@l6GKHvnt@7PoRi@wwYoPAObUDnX18zu5aTlguliSJYwX@YNp3vGMWjWzmeJNpxIaOa4dS34pYi01iKjoBLMUC2xoINGnoB4yKsPGJyxzWn0xYz7VGep@5DnAfFCrMHvuvHfYG@SkW@mPCjuxgEti4h8yz7QELJ3bfGTp9zpXZs8j2Qsf3Qp05/RN25rguG9guCixE6edBjE3DpSTBWJcGvsRw9SdXBJ@/pW3geHZSeXtiBbzyPptwTSQ6OAusyQRCSil2BMEjZ2yHzIkyIbOt0CGNokhoewOut8lc1z6zvOVaslPHYhbknQacdmgHEaqnc7psZAc2SFrE/Diwxkw5C5wIKiC17rFD2wrYk8C2VXBBc9hh35pAjhWWYOYTh4gqovNmazQy@wcPMmg@UUK3JpGUCkpP/u0nksX0Jku/rOPTlOW6tP/ZfXaR7hAMKUAMTTwJFEtlzXcsNDodG5@Z2TOOg0sJVCVoxWWGP4kMS5tAQC2CgIZFIEHaaVGfuEuMWeNKWywZlcAaoDXYQ499nuc160@DwIYcC6VaJ6i063vH0CcqG0w90ofHtgtogr7vDcI8s0@hNd8TbeSfcQ0/GTlotJCaxOpBQVafdC86BFcougRsL9Zowjf03SnHQ8kwIgOEVlCUKD4css/Z0HJcKoJ8IiWkDuxw6kZUZuoNqOXHjmcPdJaI0fcHhDT2T8HOAlGegD40Xup5XCggoyF8XlXK@ubP/2pwfAw6e/2@Hwxic/2cDfz@dAyBLS6sBVMkg/U9y@ViAS9P3EVxMDi1XGdgRcTeO49ZcCE41zN/6g6YD4bBmYOuNbJO0R2HQ7sf2cLI/WkEGfNsbJ0If@EIy0XFx1YPDcsZcN682hq7ew@t1LeFyWjjaTSsMG2yzzKh8ULZrSm7tzs2ZFN1NZs2jOM67E3P8iS8Zd5nOJ/vLdqTrOeJ41M/ciejKbwGcrxwAn8SkDL7FqoTkluJ4APzrMcVzX0RTJ130jM7E9ish56dVIzbiLABKq9Rz40pLNo0wVs1MXuwZGGwThhZFK65Cdc/A2MuGzlS2LRHzK1jC6yiuEJ7okKCI09ZrdqJB0snaj2bVbSeg9YhO4CziRtjqY5ALxUFDqiJ1lvqFGPrHFT6wkkvWpI5QzTyGHYbnLO@TZ0BvcIWno6YTLlhhA7syB@yglYsl29o/Cgw9rTn8B5vjPe2MVX@SjPvsaF9xlzLO55axzBk30MRq9@3J1Hcg1CTMEIfueoIeaIWe3U9HEnpu1d5c@8W@/slHuR9ROvFPtois4eixlC15qKXMys45j2RDZwA/cU9v8odCKdXmMuvCGVFgFfyNSIkQxOMzJ7Z/WmE7gZDPhs5/RFsl6TzRIcV3vEqeyQtc4fL0YZz1iSM2bpTlHRjnkRiXEtCoxZdpwOvT6RaKwm88ZcT3k/ZCscbCPtzEeGhllJ1w9Jhe7HSMJ4fUSwB95cM3rxnzQOMuT6hYHR1dFMYyyiKJmEN7saJRtOejmY1ngTnD6MDj1rWiIJzJ/IF3HP9njG2QnQmI@Fg9Kc9Z3alRjxtrvDXoXSKYXwYsib8/5dTmIiSGYYZtc7T7xHyUpbMh1ZOQtxlIHIkHZpShqFOIdgDeICjc6@vyDq3ex09RM4zmXqZrAKgUnO93PPH5DLYMz68ULzwcQA3M4RrkSbn0Qh60PpMtpr@xPaUzIpRZlTOUFHrPDrIZPTXvuMpF5nbt29naplWJg9oF1CDoF2CcoB2OaRxiPB0gniJPIcot81LUFo3c9lOKM/ULjXbjEKgN85Esdq1Wqmbt9pm/CzSU4VfghsCtkYP0MmozSaBqiq3zlBRvTcUtX8sNDvg1vDY9o4lezbxg4h9dnB//@Xh3pMfNWVjGgaG6/QMDwPiyzG6G0JgWUowEcE@9v2oydsGL8joj3wmp0syBVkU5WrkG8YUgk3OBd8n8BmfImhhnzo0lgwR4iyCX2lex44kizYorXoDeZFTFPHWKawPnm1yvnkclJdJ8QIQ58Qns19ALwu6WV4hgeh9veTQCUf8toK6JtZ6Di8djntDftuAUIsHMoyKFOeTXj6hKJHGUt/HnOCMo419zxeiQF@OZxmP@UOH/9skz6qbWRGmZw@niByNnuMRfAOaVq1wzGGv51yHCr2Q6MlzA1ow7W1SG7zOaG0kYiuKj6ZB5NqD@PkvPxmgAdabZ2SdhwhJT@bAS@iNmkobXttacVF64bfNLft66mLCcgONvkVhqOXOgc20qC8xTRtZAVrzPGlNWCPd4Bdvsnd0FXc6sJPnZiZcp6sDnCjtOWPeknjSaM0d4DXFrwzPojyF8YHrWwNORUyvHHvRvKIh7Jl1jMoZS1M@Peh9gJzJKMoW8ymMQNFU3GkKdVNDOhP6vK@DxpiFstUzbcMPrZ5zjRZJiO3rDFn0DxoxtKFrnQjwJYGbqyoqEzjHmK8lz@vQEMMgzJxYfds4449rfYo3DSeiKQh6D73AFffrUByvj2jVWwDXIaKaLr99H7PjhtBH3yBRaQlDW1KRc0WprtU7p1F19P3thxge53JMgz9p9nO5Qolp/mKGsVgsmUyuL9/vx@Wr1c2lxboKJ9D3MRm0b@qzGGicseVqxcESeK3PTaKQBbTJJVmnFuIT1wphIFGsZvsUzcJv7zNaGjv6U9cKFtB7THYhTjKRvG4usigzcfq@68SWmbxc5wuvBoYLMrRixm@LovQWj5j3EYDRYPyORkmPr/nA67uuCGGfPDzgeH4/oinANabzAR5JRN80v1myBd2/Tl19/4w@13bYkX9qi/vmYenNRqk@wONoLjcGhPTrxQf9myyUVjf4bbMnPNkoVdR3N6bX2CPfDzD9CllRL7y3eTaacei4fsiO@P19ukBwGYbivtmAl9XmWJ7WH4luNYc3F9soFB/R2B6/X9O4lnvsu9uVY8PC7VoLmAZDcuzx80Od2twpmeaNTmke0vieGT@v9eYn@L/JOGhaD/ftUGwzBzcbyrUeLJ58XF9BhP60jLO5cg8KlbllBaH9XpMSTRH0R2fWefL8I4aO6/ScDB2Tcx4aI5SjAtUKgCgQ4fIfw23r/dwGH@at1sju3FSJpWY@cW24a35fa1xWLJjfs4RZKHy47xq6U3tqb/QlB73XNgzofU3@4UIV4mqk48mrAeXRTswc60088fsgqWkwp7f3uh7LddDdbwxlNjqdCcLrCc2WDwEcErBe8NibTlYad0l3j6fe4/drbjRJ@rg/WBGScr6vb6rcHDAlM11aLR34thDtzA9oVwu1Xl4QjvH3xz4muf4YYYT3AVYQh/d8@UHcV6yApywov3buIQYJbnYoFKUggEVAgpZ1TkINEc@148Cq8yleNzfnyNUqJmOeHZ3T/TqNb3KrPd93v08LwbsOHIrTEH3StuTNLXV0Pu4hdOsvFsY@QP/JPBHaojlxtHmcqLFDkIw@kGZpfTVpnWa8rsW3webr0mE@3r9DmhPEuzXhfEs09dDrBzZfpU4WQlmK1s6nY4TFkR/ojOMpipXLqaokClGYdewBLcHim1K0LyD2u0KGeDfiuM6QtdssfTGrFWrmJWsyuSazbldQ5SvU@7MJ3016LIq201a3mc5oWiad6Xg1VshwVNvFqLcR1VrBGzr8IeRcVJ151phvRRCc1LQu9jsQjNIm18jyBq7NnqLheFTuB2LVXmwNPaGVl3/@/SDe@zu2UcmxE8K3HXu0X@2P7ZF/tiv4xtz3JhOL9g6JBuaertgw0O7tsRB9vT8SW36IlZ8@eFKJ92vinXS8HFIPWZJCNCrZDGSwItFoQpq5H4kZz0sllcIEZDr24GEG0SjUEVl6fZvvByV7FJAkIDQvCnwywTx7yAY2TYQHJNjrKdrW9f0TvlpKkvzz78UuFTIdMiGCE/Z823SJI8NIYPKtoX7fn0LqhMgbO/BjFIWUjGnUlFwMOoAt0lXWH1l8@wyWqCWbR8RGbCDd2zti2j7L0LY/rXLXnaGS3nv8w8/bhW7zHRsb9r/8xFAvYr3JH2k7ZijnWYJSvyS7Ws4uIHuRm2FyeibH1aINZr6fOjcq0ZuYQjBvrmQzaMz3prnd2Wd8M4jv@HnkfWjT1wvRP/CqctKi0zTTytR1xk7EtKOIlelsBIYIC5DYzWZ02oA2NqhIesbeshHZitZnZrmAN6EQl/bSxs2Pk3XL0vL6snHf7k35ustpUS@Wmrw66ZfNRotDgT3wabe1/aJz1jXCRCudzuyjQnEGtfkB0O8Y1HP2P7t/kdZbhbdvQ0SXsnyZqYvFb3Tv9MXhw8P9oyd7T54eQY2XopapB34wthYugoxg4mIGMPJdvn0NfQSOHd7sNm5xvyHdihEVhaUt1kC8xeChbs0dS6xWWZPTAhR53JPM865kxu5j6LDY1bFD3tpxw2bCZTeXTwyAlIc@OYVfTYSH4VxscFe8OjJrokIaKsTR5wLP3zZVbDWX4wuF79I7lB5XYxmLV3WBtRmJ6iqQY7kFjhByYyUu/x9JPsE4crPkhHWT5ECWbuK@xPjB3sNPnz7eX@e9xDbGWUOZW8jSiaH9GWIL@MEht3DalU7sxo9PFSSOgcd4YbwhOXdtITt1Qqfn2tyShuSYXfRt6hR89TOkzs3Ij@hszw3hSAcDeIbeeUSOBR5V5ztPYvtJ85icggL0@TiXZ7JEuGFzfXcZjuMMsVH/lSic5niccrjpgEbHNr75878ShzI6EeCfxfAQ8J8J@IVBClrfxRcyzlVDavn84SELMVqJio@t2VKdaMCgAcnxMC9yxtDgKVcIoQthF/Vd0FHan0OfaAQokzwfOTvOzw66Cm3r1gyDxvdj3x3qfJPEnqEd4Cv5Lu@XUzojA/9sbJe3t0wDQmqnCUHNEQS1iSCoqjWYkHTqTJqven3WaDSYHCJGtpvbdaFII229KMmv5oKmgSuJUKDNUAZFFiWQ14qLKWkrZ6pUlHphxsywbh2jvGgXDBQKB4CiUrIX60PGSOTHqkKje/Ys4k71PAlxEF94PhuTnvhJqYSQBkKCtipLa7a7WIynjckla9aXm0F@RmhHhFaTN5lO@wXrRB2vGx/pYTCYv9lgSB7gn2845zO3nr314zzK1cM4VBt298jzaXvmAaRlStEolgxzW13qKXJMCvJSv3gLkugJ6Fl923ntT8K9e/sPPzk4PFo7jsIxM1fRMizTauQ6mp5vd@dA5orVJ0r9@IFx9OjjB4kql6VaTHMIYzHXuSrmJm5XJb2G@zOxE7LOm2esMTILH0qYT5S0B3xJYJ36ItdYQrwnlm3XuCrqxWW722h1vNQa@7ebDo@l9CwZF6BOyI@OZdgGn/Mw2d954p/AXvRk074oL05G9iU@Y/Tj90Xy9YdUIqLmvFk@S5PsJNFBlWLLGNinhjd1XUlf7DHJaaWxUjNVhgZ0QzDkZzWEeInU8DiJwCYJvGDbl9aW7pdlYnGN5qyXS87biFR1IOaI/Nyc5WF6EGAGzLFD7qbFTJIf8sJc4uHSMgamNDSd5bOscz6jgMOYL4UPHL5LYgXncQ3mOUf22NGeJPKQ@1gcP4E7o7MWI9TNdXp1q9mesfkpifedTNHDietECh0Jmek0U0NtFJUqYDZcm06UNKrd@PgKS06Z5PhBlcMp9HXoT9hidnzfTqDHmCCx@1MQhzHY7JPpGHhD/nhs01hhs898DYWhx0wiRBtclLgO@nhQBnd9ZM8GzjHGG0XNwzF9ZJqLIy6WmsOsNiMnR0p@SGv8y4r5XsdyljRmtS3d8Qb2TMmcZdRal7SD9MzZs9OMKq/ZAD8bFB8UGlw9JJS4DCuK@@7igM0Vt1Ctzt3Bag@qVvVRKNEBFsT44HgUBZ8CxEiqDMfWhClTfsoqZDrjr0pH8fJhFKhMa9GodsY8lsvx2QEePENnvOSQQ45LhxwVOtqqGE20M6WG3oAeb5wJa5u63gXMmagsTRP7ewg6aEqsSgglUaTGyWIYxl@NJDrDPIgkEs80ZyvRrDwA1sZs3pGPR7wDQhe81qx1hy18wqIHCq1Wq7W4NVadYpXBLNbHI90A2Q3OLok7od/4UAK0Rq4MWPcw33PgUO7@2PY89FcFNjNG72TWFEYWqPnkOwH5@anNFOeQEiL@KD7lAEFTK@54P3Ph@ohq0kadTy7rlxj9X3Vo@B/GAcC58QNDN@oXStptnhsIydSWkh41zVwpm8ulvayS9igouXOH5qSXacQ8L3VZl2dA0tKuWoc9I0Zqpr162moo6UGzmOUl8JrLqRco8C409Iu0dWmk7yCmyCMlEL1TSYcqdYeCrpuXkI96SNrIw2YuFJnJMzr/SuzTTi5HMujplyTAO6NzlOOjS@fI4LPgehzqGsfjxI2sNMt336XMbcy6drdLir9bLN3OpljqrmxkO/efP793Ws@0rWFR/7J7eHJ4@IXaUTKpeweyuSXXWdaQUka28HbHMF69eoUgkLVbekvvqm0t020rrZ2dbD2/Xcnm7@bNTL6eYq5ZME1VKRbVo86WV3ccZxIOBvj4IzrMjSCoRk1zC5diHmYy5VLm6AWdxtu9jT/@j2v@SvfbPCVO5ijr122VKV/OpFTrFsyptH377i2Iauf4VavdZVLqnZQ6l1KvGq@kFGLdVKvVvbzMaW09h26X03KNdqOht1qzltZttaXUhZSaXUqpokxKykqp5qzxmBNr328JqrkvofBP8Wxo3fbk8NP9vaP9fLGhpYoP9u7li0dPP06ZeCsvXimzRK@P9/fuHzx9ki@KUj98@Pn@00Okh93W3bs5XdO0u3qrCylmH@VauWYURez5yyw6yv3W7KmhNcD0Uyn1mGNqHYjRUYH/Vkq1U21lt7hbLLiF04J5Yp488g/m/@zRwQEynFnhtR8URoWROTBNc@tg@@DurGA/LZwXzmeFsX9gDgDa@CuMATqF4axwXPAKnmkuU3vP//jAf3Tgg5SPYtGsEBHVwhDP44ODRyA2BPfX@HMKBZJyVjjFf8E1@fXiJebKhU5HasNgu@XtSXH7yzYfAcrVbtueOVFXZvlMp12tVjPdesoIOx1DWL1chMkSxuXly5f3957svXxp0Kx41kjn7ua0u7iarVwjfuymBi1Sod643ZEyytmzZ8/o8@zs9ExAHHh2xp7FF94Meaci@/7dGPXZ4vnsDNfpNURWAbZyKUq73L24VFX1VidTz4iaKIqNqEaRzc6sOGRFmQcLVbgKs0QD0nZZbbW2y3jfrqiaUqDcLfWF2WjEWUXVD@TMTPaDDLu4FH/KxWVD4ZdKf6pKifG9pSrIVst4m10os4bSUCgNSVTq4rJFIMe7ANRW1K56eSnScFfUhqDZUlFBmtj9f/r3QxZOWCZ1maIRwmNbZRXTRlvd2lYquWr817yNyihyKVNCHeWMlWm372ZL2Z2t9m43280qjaye7bS6s@VLzaQYTC6xmqaZIu1JKb3@WDaLcoasqE6Lpb5r6y4mcaVqPaNkxcWy86tiVnPZ3N12tloV3LLZt7dVFAdxGVcKlsYU1mg15s2/sAS1hc8FixUM@PICFiHyMMAo8SpopzMrFDh@vddMX6Ssyzonzy7lBDs2LE5eydT58rh8IaetoG125Us5fdG7pIE4a6p8AC1v1evZLQHvVOpw@2Y2zikgJwaRYYdWn/cweHqypAxUrKJSzZ597HgYfFdMO1cul40i7rOPtveLM6lOy8hizVrWZGHprFLlBFMsDKsSYr0eGvqM7RQQy7uuFTB/OLwt0hG0sp5tI26wXZcWYCimQ2jjDs4wj7gtpeARENEgG9f40LKntn02nZ7Z8@ueE9as168xJeHXt1//@k/w@T0@vxDPX/yPapnu3379n//bN7/5LRL/CZ9/xOcfvv36L38iPvz9D/j8r6W0P8SfJTzxkUDrP3z79S9/9@3Xf/YVPv81/nx19fPNr/5O/P/v@I/A337zqz/QTbyA1q9//s1f/hQi/orgPwWM/zj5ZzG4lCrAnyUgyv31FeSff/v1X/wuhn@6jLKUjqI/Q/pvltJ/JknUmLdZeScBTOkRLedUTbG55VAyoMCuSj9Ci46n/RHtLzoRxRQI9guSTu1fLFYr5Uq1VKzkK9XKVtncLpfzZjFv7lR2qoU8womKuV0pV818Zata2traquaZWSxXdxD8eQNnaBgYnk1ZZhzAnJKO4jboELOvj1pSamAPEVHfYjNloN5KDZIENq0wuVTpFDCL5UG/wlR2QeOMwkLM/SC5UshP4V7Lu9OKvL0j17J4yrtyCSA375nCChn0RDnTkWW1Xe3uyjtluYZgRsvcMXeZvFPFbGBnR1brclmWt1lxR5afO3Qqhcn1S8ibKGJeE4bhSNcZPpomUf6kKYRR5KrCuHlXO7Lo/KInZZRMZqeYyaiZOojclpf7n1qnmqFiol6JYDJ0CsGqGFbqgR1NA0@pavCcTKuq9Ush0r9Zkik4wbzDCij25ywx8d@uypQMlIZSJVatci9by5ta/q4kuvW2KaUupQEdNtyqsnq1TjEVhppGS0pnSKxMSUppJX/LT6XTacRkT1pyST7QG0YcXrUMHlt1KNyiQEdP4rYWM6TApk2aAX0pVIyXlTLV5ZiFqdwfeeng0ARNqU5@Wk5NxMhwTiN@RwjUeJfih0LY4cV84X/q8aWE2iPStFU74sew212mvvvMcS8qJa3Fp0CYB18y6PbyqPpi50XlxaOnB08PHtwt1Cq1Cpx3Knyr@mXznfdJPVWbZEpbmRKiumZKVM7cUVOt4o4eWuepbryVrGztqAxv3DUXzdSQ4o95@LEenixBG97PTsc8rIUglR8Mjo@d4g8evXqbNoxMhjEzvf1Oa4j/Bm73DkQTK/J2WVZpCz588fLFyxQcMJOLZZhgzmCxi12JdGZZj//Z2ZD/2fYiIcRr8kb5tprFZOyLItxDtbpd2U5J3xnG@9bOkDufRg5tTK@m403zyL3AeWTRHNubzyUBPJq@sYO592DkPmh5hPzHclrsUpaS@HeakSaRXLy3EWAFx/0831RhWTq73@7CtyQbcgrl0p6QOt9CEr2QFepiq49IOPU5CC7kBDCjL4hEmjMqTtOsM6dBxPDEVDPmQFdSItckkJaYuBROV61Ly3tjXJIWSi/JslQ@lxPol0IsUZ/@eCCqLfLmrxBvTGcI@kpcWr2C0C50aemiU8jE1fyQavStSJlTyLPvXY0r5TGrVpM6cREWmXH6oikupWyUH9clqnZ2Upd@rPTVC5rt19@N79zpv5i0x926Om5G9MzlxnCdJ4ojULJRc9zUzPoEwtajdi7ndJtj9cfKhAs/bhaADN5EOVQv5i3tNePmCtX8m7anvfO6@QdtL2d289N89nnzTd5qFvIzfKC2vJv/EspLVKlEzTc5r2418KGFhxVNYBjJWfXVLUsUOVHc5pu21W0W1LqLgrncA1QGcoZtN5frqmDuInO9YN29c8fKua1Z3dU0lbBelHYftCMA3VyT3muK1ZjtvmlPUb6m4NkEG1eF8Ci32gagB/nq0LFovoXoQsYZiTeDeONmM/t8N/s827x9@017po27eaH@WmHR8CT8jIRfthEl@3zZsLhKeDStyB85tY/0bMjkPKwPSs5PlkoKCbPPkTNZ9IZLckX8C9bJohYtdcZ7lWwY@GPxJSq@Rk0/mEAnMHxKo0MTKLsX9h0nRhenXSaOPaCD7U6YR/zraRbHoLz4JwgoszPb3ZUS1vFGGjjTMZWezSw6q8K/7xtQbM9/ziLsBw79tML7ndgmXzd3bEm8dPTw@T5DbFbaXnJ2qnQh3eJ@IQz6bUKhPn5RuKxLtwhJbJ82oRNaCwYOYrc8J6XhyZWkEir6gsBsxpkUi8UNhFKsNx0OxdFA@g5eSI4GHTnprCZ6UywGOvMGMZz8a7LiW2RPDiA4HM5PeBzpFipBMlAdnC5rwdGyO3dY/NpoIt7cARZHI7zXOZOQ1iQF8w@QFDRIytewUQgpmEC2W5RDu/4rjLb@dYzikzMKCuRe58UBGr34hZynxeNQHBgjvalCDGqLW7de55pbsUD456EjyiPv8rtUPJLW2L2DR4dPn@w/frR3hLtZ3KpIKTp5EvrOoDb/9YG1rzFP6OvJPcfjW9x967Fp/7tP@ggNEFbBpPwB/drFgH3y9FPMCz67n6ezzlA9HUCCgbuhX5tTskP@fdFQ94Nj48w5cYz9lYOJKCR208Ma/7o/Py7v0Y8f0LSRfuBifoxtcYotpBmLNUgOZ678UMrYDsP429la8nsp/Ddh@IG@MZ1LQy@Mv83NtyiSL@HzNX2a1ub5TlHgHDv8RzBGgsBKef5t6UgU5/1Dom9hD6zIIouWqpVCocYKeQLMBCgmQCkBthKgnADbCbCTAJUEqMaAmVA2BWWzWCmVthfgzgKsLMDqHNwqLMAFha3iAiwtwK0FWF6AC25bc27bFU6XpRJt8q6LcA155lYlyaMjq17EE8sgY15N3IKgxTVMFN9aSwS/ymoiZqIxo4fGASEVi9uLd3ifBLepCKnyQo684Cze4kSMVZKYRnCD3Q8CeKX9Gf1GBIxOrTE6ZiRJcLus79oWggE7QpTSfAD7t9WaOK4anNfmg5RNFJrm/B3FbczWUMYkK4rNZ0N2cVO2oFbcSE2cDWZzxSwFYbGQQsra6gkqTnFrJW2Z6m1ysKTRazCKAoPaYCGlu8TzSTDdyLL0fpYrBDeyXBNK0C1vKkW6UTjxZlKUj/@cWjPhJ@IUm7c2woD415a4DVxpUDq33Lwwa/K3X3/139m3X//yt@yb3/z2//zDfyL47@j2PxGzsOIc4Re/pNtf0@2/0O03dPvVUiGOX6rJ33z1N3j9j3/LvvmTX4qsv/idnN@aE0IOJS1K/vpP6fZTuv29nC/PEX/9c4FIReT8pbQSWinA@sU/MQZuRGVO7KvfMybnEGAoseW1RR/vquoVAnM1tDnUvZov7v1RQGovqDkE97n4zVy85agB1CXigUU/H7ToewhnxMY@eem@1R/RUbo4yQ8p/ulTCOOH@jHs7WyAoCeel2dQ@3/PaiyTIxwk8@PaTeHD4/rH9ZYXuYSbkw1Ih/eEFMHqXJLwPJRg33wmcB7qNOtRuQ0JG4n1@xn9PFkygMiJZTmRgmlQzCsp3Ta7LP5NHfwnZfLcaGkYEsed@a8tSfGpMHOJ4Yq7udJs4HI1JccWzmilKE@wxxM0CYrN9U2KpReuhfxVcouWi7vN/sGDKx2Grh5CzJNljzRn1GSyfAMuaTrGVyniKq3iC3ljhHahVupKy8dDNyHLX3zxhSwtpRXIhoKBwiksVUq4jHmWuZpVXMoqLmVBZkGT@5pysXhFBj5wkF9Urx6IXXVRq8UWxkU9J2kHEgNzQbHelh@603DUXCfNPfKqs1snvkTS7DbjftLxuM9pMVldKwCaq2WaV9tyM@nCGs56Q20uSdpeSVlpresprZRZ6hRce9JVLc1bzqxuarlVhu8hbXZzH8ioWPhXMtI@kNF2@WZGV5uVyq6Qv16/N7udxE3MPfyCmOj4qZUBiobGr2B6C3dEEgccVNT/Cw)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)

### Explanation

Emoji-gramming is another emoji-based esolang. Every command must start at new line. Lines which do not have valid commands are ignored.

The program is:

```
♈  ♈ = 8
♈♈   ♈ *= 2   (♈ += ♈) (♈ = 16)
♉♈   ♉ = ♈    (♉ = 16)
♈♈   ♈ *= 2   (♈ = 32)
♈♉   ♈ += ♉   (♈ = 48 = '0')
♈  ♈ ++     (♈ = 49 = '1')
♉♈   ♉ = ♈    (♉ = 49)
♈  output ♈ ('1')
♈  ♈ --     (♈ = '0')
♈  output ♈ ('0')
♉  ♉ += 4   (♉ = 53 = '5')
♉  output ♉ ('5')
```

Other languages:
 Fixed PingPong (both return value and error introduced in previous answer). 
Cubically is currently broken on tio, I checked it locally.

To save some bytes, I used parens to fix Paintfuck code in Underload.

#### Test driver

Pretty printer in the test driver didn't work properly because Incident tokenizer and Hexagony pretty printer printed invalid utf-8 chars.
Hexagony pretty printer is no longer needed because Hexagony code is on the first line, so I commented it out.
Incident tokenizer is fixed by escaping all non-ascii characters with \x?? (there are currently none because Emoji-gramming detokenized offending token).
Whitespace pretty printer has been rewritten so that it doesn't print out emojis and such.

Comment: Cubically's Tio is temporarily nonworking.

Comment: Set's TIO should work now

Comment: Set's TIO does work now

Comment: Also Deadfish~ too

Answer (score 8):

## 111. [Del|m|t](https://github.com/MistahFiggins/Delimit), 3575 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";!*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@   x/"78"oo@
#~
#z#111#y#y#111111111#_#xxxxxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[       _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                           _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO4O6O@MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                x_
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002614 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3672 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIkthzI/wP9qUEchoACYAEKUr8ljTd6t2emR7Jre6ZuSHZahAERbRAAAOAEtVqTaxf7m7XF/Z5b72xN3feud2wIzbCfjqHI85xG@EI3@v9ivkDnn8wzqzCF78k9Z7NbhKFqqzMrKysrKyqBDTUg8kPP@TwQ45d@@rMdkMSmkFIRr51Yfoq@fCK7OtWUKtUOQ6hDvyz2dR0wqDJ5YhGLMewRnBLQvfcdKy3pg/ZFeL57pmvT0k40UNiBobumQFxZ6E3C4k7Xl@rSg6n7htLwYpTyzkDqND0Pd8MafE2eenY@nQ40pcKaovUPB@KA/LYtN9N34XEcKdT3RkFHGP/2HdHMwOxhxMTECFDY8s2A86Aul3iRUJQMUFyxDf1EQPjxq5PsAqZntvEIobnkaGtT1SD2BbAPinXiYkNIG@hPEcCd2pmOQ2IY5ojEnimYY0tg1Il5jw0ncBynUAllnFOLi3bJiPThgopK4YMyMgsyGQxwio3cjkCH8NbYjy5y5sA45hx401P92njXRQaSCKWwaWvex4wCfI8AcZDawodZoVCQEw9sFAhoEpgOiMqNy9RFZfoTraV5MLSiQ78znyKOzD9EJqnUrxkYvomoNSTHhMvfSsEEaBYD8ixqfvkhW@a0qLiLJAEYi5SCLEhKu22dls4PHoiQPexGqruhVzOr7741x9xOlE7JH/agm@H51vc4aePyXW@j2mmKtDFni/qEul8TYJSv2/Cd64NS2f@DQdYOZCKTUquF5Z0xQMGlRAYLOmYxJRyUVE9O0OYtJf6IqNUDGoEvUGeOuQzmbbMmPk@joVUqPo5NNp2nTOQJzTWnzkoD4fslKELDBe0WSbmBUjNdVgfuZdUwi8mFnRagF2iD0FAuoGyZ@OZChRGNOheJNGYbuDaMwoHNYMQFRCkAlUR49Mx@YyMdcvGKlCOqBjXvhnM7BDrzJwR9jwMWXOkkpgNwx0h0NS9AHI6IKUZMIammZFHmQJg6AiXNhWLvvvLvxmdnQGeA8Nw/VGkrp@RkWtQy6NTZmFME1RY19FtyhbAyUidVQcCF7ptjfQQyTtXEQnKBKV66c7sEXGBoH9pwdCa6BcwHMdj0whNpuTMXMlkqp8ze2ExzYWGT/UhdCwlQGnTZitk/xH0kmEylVGms3BcJ4p3SISg9Erca4p7W30TeJNUqZAvlc5aoG9qgWbBnXCb4nx2kPYnas8Ly8VxZHuTGVgNKHECD@yJj8I0dGhOgGYlBBMukyEVNLVFoOp0kF6agm@SIYzsuGFUR5gOYH0FR26EIe3TGG5RxcxRRsNAO0HJwmDFTNjuJRCmvKEhBZ12kLh@pgOpMGrQAWsQo0hzFpt27oCmI7ahSerK0ILeQT0AYxN1RqaNAF6tMBjAxnovMyim@hVgMZiRTnuSWGPo5CnorX9FDBMHA4wKk1k6JDKjihHA9IUTWVmp1Gp3dH7olw6UL8F6vC3d2sfY@KVuPiBj85LYunM2089wBnWgim4YphdGIwhaEoQwRpYNIc1UIquuBhMuv79Mm1q3yN5naKD1Yb0X2Wgd1T6aRhUbRjnRIx@AjCwfxot9tUwdAC6WiPOvEWSBgdf8BhbiqQmUzJybxiyE4QaKfDmxjAnoLnLnsAHLrOMyecjKUgeTo4wT0siM1n1Y4dRSkoVsbEShYI@u4gGrj6i6Cxm087MZt2PWg@kaxG7CIlioTK5a0lXQvUhoMJ@foC8B5i@evOnIShyMRJ4gYBjqMExBWSZh6AVNMDdWOJkNVejW0gv/6ml45GDPlkL/ygpdlh7a7rA01QMYTKWYQsmYDa35UotoXiLwNwF3AdP4OCAdsP9fzUBFRGEcCFKL5j9C4EwRT6dWioL98gBIgVSQlDgOVHTBnoAFOLlyDJFXqd6rMEJ4mfA4yngJElgrkcsjd4omg3xOpxf0Fz70wcyMwbRw3lU4ATkoBuH1juuZjigsKKUgUYKi1KLegSCob1zLEa@Fra0toSl0BRlSe5BqY2oPU0VI7dGUQlMIp2KK1pBpCkt7tAbmDYSbXox5Lg2w2@boAr21PFHvNZvVgaz3tOhawasEdgnMEEAreAE8gtTpYFKS@O4lNFQdjlnrnzPJjqg2PDedM86ce64fkk@PHh@eHh@8@EmHL80Cv2Rbw5IDE@LpFIYbuMD8mvrgy8bVIfncdcMO7TDMp9BPsx7u2HeniXUIONOYuITPV3n0zBZ8e9W7iku3sXQWufaYT9E@AdqRC8@F7gzGPXjF1tQKn1Jf3HZwxKS6EJc@guYwBC/Agn0CLhT5xAromiPLKJdIvM/xTCOqi7aJT0sqzPu7gLEAdta7Wj8r81lUtAK089zFQZimTsuqVltAAWuJ1ZpjK5jQnwXQFbZWS2jtYDoc0581AM1oWoU5GlcdKJeP0GfFmd11YYVyScGmruMyVkBelqOXntOLCtZ4HT@LRm@BmaE5noEfWxpaDqbvAFMadQo5Hg6tTaAgF2Q9vq4B82fDdWIDGzhZmRfJguDDmR/a5ii6/vNPR9ABq90z0a8CcJDPk8QpyA27Shlv7K2oKt7Qn/U9@2Zmw/LpDhyGjk6xbieJ9bhwZBNFmeg@9OZV3JugjfgDVvoufYehYs9GZnxdT4TKdHG6ZbUda0p7Eq7oO1BzvKH6krPA6uOiwrddfUSxsMWeZabdyzrCnOtn0LhSZgGq@sN78BnP6SRd3cF8GM7YLy7o7upIy8PvbQM0gizX9KFmltxAH1obpIhM7GxSZDY@cP5SxrZ@zpKnmFzfVNYY3zqD1WN83QQGHhU4vZ5umKVLetloU5xZ4LGuwNQt@Hyb/W4Cibd@ksQmQGimTX/eR@2oIhgwNpBV3FBRMiKyloRq68MrnOMn768/SPCsWCQK2JOOUSyWq0Rx0/VOunXjeZvrG0ZUv9FYX5vt8lAEhgtLU/OuMQsTjTXVbaUyyiQ32tzYJ0pT60ySfqGDt2TrAShIGInZvIBuoT@3KS3OHcbM1v00dYvKpuzEy9pNK6O0jmcZrm1FmhnfbLKFy25qigb37@hPWhXvVuU7As8Q52UlSa0f0K4R4upkgx7dwzyxhQEuvTKKobqbZGe4l/jdOHon7oXJftfPUW/XcnUP86PYVDNgtbFafWTcpa648UJ/1kvxfC1XoWGvzW@SZ67rw8owIBW1jB6NQ3cLYYa2bbb4efH0aLNOB5btBuSE/t4mC3Bhg4D9rtfmrNgs3VGMCRtjSXp9tbVM0emNHNDfDZ2r22euvVM/K@nws1EDZv4YrXx0va@FSyyUpt1poRL/xnW06LrRtJ/D/7uUA3ccwJZb6OgkyfWKstGcReuizQ2EdQDuMK1v3JNyPdEsPzBvVSnWFb4xudSv4usfMY9sknM8j3hX1E8Gvw4rNOqQCH3mO/8x1LZvpza6n7VaQbt7VyMy3Xxum2C76e9K55JKWXvPGlq5fH/bNbZn5sxca0uOhm9MUKDbuvz@TJWjZuSjJXQJhIeHRAnU22gVeC@ucWbHu1tNj25bMNzv9GvWGh0PfG0Pl87HkDjGxGrFM2fmLXRuRnbPZ87z2yU38eIx7o4WmMSS97VN9bu9pwWHPDDpd70paeIhJKx13Sl4E849@j9CSrc32O8CYpqTYn5j4Q6FfyveJkm2xMCTBc8EetU6DxTc5tg0BywansqmRToFbjRgVeaY4RX@bpL2OpM6dF37fXoHLOvIQocN3FA8Lb2rl5rk5Go6BB/OSPfr7tED8YIRpIWL440dewwow3virK7uV90yX2V2r9ZS/rFrd9vdOzr9OY5dTa2ru3cAPj768PCTg/tha6jVOwAjC@DFDi7dRsOtN7bZlh7sCjkBq0R7hPRIMjkjCOToLBXyLD86OQuS4@ncU8fwTXpiEG9KkxyeY8ymsCgIXV8lFE4U9WJRkjhWCf3KMwfAYih6QIhnNOzsMSDg7YcU1hqTXo/kr@fNclO7IR3CN3kyGDCs9LTgcO7Rk73nrGovrw86eUFRhLzQd5qkLFBQ04Zpfi2ovgA3tuiF8Zk2nTj6lB4LYTpuaYudPYH3jQeOE90Z2SZ5CdpK1ySuz05Q2DHdC9x3@qffj6Jz2DMTGjm1AjDmZw7GDrhTc@Je7jG6EfUDz9PxHBdxwMrbZoc3yqMDElxaoTFhx6@wOHj55EU9OjuLohrg5hjNQoYL1qk4UIAHPWSdxrgZuSbTpIhwUituFCy/ZlOHXFqjcBKo4Eo7hknP5pIdYUghmBP6LmqiTJ6SkYnbACNk7M0M@tZ23XO684yc/NPv2YkhFFqoQpiOydMj7AxFggpPj@kMw50B1zGSt6bvRiAiChkWkTO0qzAOTJYvEWOi06NM0EQlPshDMuww79HBCVEOiYAhGHji0LLGYv7g@Y8/65UHna/JtGT@809L0nUkN/4DZVcLeJnEIK0b1KtscRmK01KB8Pk5HzULD/vp2XaiVFHYjIhp2l3xwdyUxglQvTMv6cEcPX110OTiAbwTwPiAW4miZoOmkxdnbIgrJyGpYZyKCSKBFIssIBj5gYdMWCU/J@/IBHVFMYhWK8MdE4iN55rTzofxrm01u7teemwOZ3TX6aKiVqod2pz8aQcsIKZ8c@TiyXfvVf9yUApiqfT78w/KlTmIzfUB/GEJR87hp4@v82q3/O5dAO40z98ILXZqAMM7f3389Pjw5MXBi5cnIMYb1srcE9ef6qmJQCXwbFjyTFybhhKAPHzLDO42Gw@o3eAeRICiSPI6aYODScBCPUgMSyRWXuHzLMnKqCVJypYKI/Mxtkhk6sgx7e2oY4Uga@bkWAFQeDAmZ2BXY@ZBca7XmCvaHJ50oEEKNIiCJwwnd@satlhK4ZnA9/AehB41IwtFm5pCrQfCtjLgiG8Gw5hc24ib/0ecezCP3M05Qt3FOQBzd1HPEH5y8PSTl88PV2lnyEYwKyCJhmSitw7n4FCBHRxTDccIgVhv3CjCIzYMYPcn7BxYt1PTFpALK7CGtkk1aYyG2YaxjYOC7v0GOLgJ2hGVHNgBGNLRCCzD8CpEwwIWVaVHduzcTnEInwMBqMk8JxOeQ9igs3rSD4bjEhxC4zWrnKdwFHOwLlimb5a@@8u/YQEy/RDSP4vSY0j/BUu/KqGAViMqGI@JaFAsnz09JgHMVqzhU32eaRNOGDghWQ4sBK0pSPCCCgTBGbNpe1M8Yu8zkCd0AggTLR8aO0rP9AciHrE3SyWc389ce6zSIyJzDv0AtpKeuH81w3glsM@lndrOtlYCJpWLGKFiMYSKxxBKUhNUiLuwvM7roUHa7TbhA1gYmJ2dFhNkKa@/qvKvE0bzAMsxV6BHoA5USWtAWTeqJub1oiZhVRyFgiaQQQtmedYvMFGINAEgEmY7kTx4mIncSFTQ6Y45D6lRvYpdHPAvHJdMUU40ai1GpAAihlviuRXdTY8i8Fg2o81qthv4zxHsBMGa/DrV6b0i/bDvDKLwKgIK83drFMmB9M/XxFwl2nOwGlolLgdGYWvI/onj4uHUE@CWiJVSpVrSdqTMSOEjVMAvjot3gBJGAowsw7TeuF5w8Ojw6UdHxycroUEUUlgGE4jQbRf7iir3BklCWNL6WKgfPimdPPvwSSzKLFfp2g4h0gXeMpvrqC1zuoH65@wcaJU2LVghpJXvi5iuDpUndA9kFXtaWsoAPmL71CtURen6pjdod/tOboX8u3WBfDm1gMoFqX5Aw/gEssbmPI1Pt15ghHOgxtEOFT6NUjU4ukx2o/s0e3PAUBIvnYYNxedoGDRU6cIK7qLkzGybU9MTNj4vthdaJvEgAbXECNK4GcZezDVYnJhhDRlOyRrcyllFlicStWg1wBtqJn2Eojpia0Qaw6g7sDzwYdlPoQNqptlKkgbcwVriaZguP2BJg2t4usq6oisKMBjJ3v/IomdEuh8HmCQlJ@bUUl7E/KD5SEOBwJxhiMsE2mZbw5be6c1JEiNyW5SQGni2FYoYnjNXcaUGrRElbIDWtk2M7mk3BlEoEYkjfoo0aOh4BvI6dj2Sro4fm3HqOSyQyOMZIAdlMMlHsynAjenluYlzhUk@dRWoDHIUYiZ6QEWM2qBORzWgrk7M@cg6g/lGlGQwTB9oWhpupEtFWNUKYI2ZqH6MhxpZwbxXiFRGYnpPVy1nZM5F4VKQmgOUDuQLl59fCBK/ogM0TisK2hotB2zFJkMPo7GbBjstmYVGIzEHiyOo0VAnAYfhO@DjA8WT0P8EkjCTiuOp7hFxRiPeAqISeiv2RUcOQl8iShdntUvikGKRrg7gQgtUQmuOacqycYNExDBjsdSBfsbcwBnh5a3lkZ6mqgNIUyISyePC/hE4HbgkljhwJaFKk6KFaRj@NZGjS1gHIUfsmqdkOVyV@wC1tpgO5LMJHYAgC9pq0n1IUpuQjkAm1UajGfXGolFsEFCL1flILQHaNcYu9jtBvlFIBkgNTRlAPYL1ngUGZf9j03FgvIqgM1MYnUSfgZL5khw/XiInEbQ5SiHHWPxJFOMBjOYWzPGhcG274NXkSy26uGzdwOz/uo/T/zhyAK5KPyqppda1mLc7VyVwyaSumJ90tGK1UCzmnYKYd9ApefgQ16Q3efB5TlVe5ecApORtqQX6DD5SJ@@08npbzI86lQKtAbfFonQNFb4OSup1Xr8p5R@CTyFDjs9Gp5gPJBwOZVXVboA/HCH5kgw6cy3yhJ9jLDKSz1vFIvKg5k@Rga9L/ZMinV36JyW6Cm5Frm7pbBqbkUWPJemJlSdemACj7GZi0Wto0aONvtMYGAPv4u3MNWXrvKQffshpO7De29upiu5epbpVyJHcPl8q9B9/@eWji5bQ08cV9avB8fnx8RdSXxRyj454bZtvbRVKXK5UKL/bLZVev34N7ifpddWuOpB6ijDoid3d3UJL3qkX5H1ZE@RWjthaWdMksVKRTvq7ul4oblf2nZZlWV4wGsHXnYC3DU5YB1XjAXxE7VgQalXh5BVGZu5twT/6Hz7JLf5u0Zwom4KsfrYkIn4153LdB/iQ0s7W/gNg2CzST7O5D30zL/G7dd5197nc11zubU7TtNwV/NPiT@40N48/XO51@zWXA6c81@0Obm6KSk99VVTV00FRKbZ77bba7c67yqDbi9aCp4TLXXO5@Q2Xq/Ao3gKX68zbzykDvcddxknxKwD9BK5tZdDzjj85PDg5lCttJVd5cvBIrpy8/DCnwV0tvcXCKt4@Pzx4fPTyhVxhtX789LPDl8eQHwxOu/v7RVVRlH21O@gBDx8Uu8VOGIbky9OCSjZ/Ttek2C2Xe9ydvywpbWD1kyjnOaWh9OGuLwGld1yul@uJe5W9StkuX5S1c@38mXuU/N8@2jnaf3Z0BIXWvPzG9cuT8kQbgaDnZfNl@ap8NS9P3SNtBEkT/pWnkLTK43n5rOyUHU3LIrvl//TIfXbkAioXqoXzcohYy2O4nh0dPQNkYyD8Bv5Z5TIyOS9fwP@yzTr91WmZEKnc73M9wr82QdNVTVDLgrojCNagtuN9dX1T2fmqR6fAWmPQM@dWOOCJLJz2e41GQxi0cqWg3y@xcc9XYOggyM3N6enjgxcHp6cl3BeYt/PF/aKyD59Ot9iOLnu5URelqra3@pwgXn7@@ef4/fzy4pKlaILlfZ4UZm9oAj4XG@ouJjbogSj2aoPrG0mSHvSFlsBaIoom@HUir/XnlTGp8NRdaoCx1Ko4Je/UpG53pwb3O3VJEctYyir0ec/z@rxKF5EqPbXsdA58X79Cl1HclsBe93ndP@3zvcqg02nUsG5VaWwT11caVYmXpFdaux2RqEiQzQtz3vUFcn2T/Sde37RF@pHwnyRhZvTblUQolmpwN78W522xLWIeZGGt65suJincNaR6ojSQbm5YHvyKUpvh7EogOFwp/3/67wYk8IiQu8nhlOuQ7ZoE63BT2t4R68VG9K@zBY0R@apQhTbygi70evuFamF3u7c3KAwKYrugFvrdwTz7kYQcAaWOlbCj5VCGXE5tPee1Ci@gUrZw99m1TdWGVXG10VrUCuFULCx/6lqjWCju9wqNBqNdKLzbgvED6IAYD58cKDIRSbvbTrQrRSl14XtNIoFD@uYaFI6VwQwuRtvM/f68XKbwrWEnf53Tb1oUPbnhhdaC3lL0otCi5w/8NZ/X/Z424G/4/PXwBj2dgibRCbW23WoVtll6t95qQUEhKilDSZSEAjPQDTqAYUJDzRJA5BI0qjM0zywHvJsFGRVrtVqpAr/zD3YOK3Ouhfv07FCAV3g2kEi9QRHmSBA0OHCmh9Dxl2S3DIsl29Z94o7HWywfVgVkaJrgmJm2jTtc6DSD72iPLmGhtsXlwOCAywjF8Jke6@bMNC9ns0sz@Tyygqb@5g2s@ejn@29//afw/T18f8Guv/hvjRr@fv/tf/gv3/3mt5D5j/D9n/D9h@@//eufsi@9/wN8/1cm7w/RNwPHvhzg@rfff/vL333/7V98A9//FH2/Wf5@96u/Z///d/QPk7/97ld/wB92A7h@/fPv/vrPgcVfYfrPIA3/o@yfRclMLkv@LE5Cvb9dAv7599/@1e@i9J9nQTL5UPVnkP@bTP7POA47c4vUdmVZVVX4watMP/Sq5l/FINrmaTbHPcNNtobGjhwtrAEp32xwPwE1mOJTE/jUXoj@FizBypyKSlOpNOq1eqNaqcv1Rn27pu3UarJWkbXd@m6jLIOrVdd26rWGJte3G9Xt7e2GTLRKrbELLrkzssalEjggGs8TmoCVPoaHtzGw3lUnXS43MsewznlA5uJIepAbxRlkVid8td4vE54txUQikWuc/EQSwIocOBfL8gxMfm1vVud3dvlmAa78Hl@FJG3wXCRlAYYvL/R5Xuo1Bnv8bo1vgounCA@1PcLvNmCNtrvLSy2@xvM7pLLL81@CtptnikDme3zrBniOhZG0hsA0qaoEvorCYbnXYQyJfEMkdFw0@jyzGmwICqIg7FYEQRJagGSLz/aK1MLWQeNY22LmeJArMNeA6a7lm@HMd8SGAiaYKA2pdcNY@lcZnvxzWBHqPq7KKMkm4XcaPGYDSFtsIKlubVhoypoi73PMHuxoXO6GG2EQ7HaDtBot9Bxhzmp3ubyAbAlVLqdU3W03l8/nwQl90eWr/JF62i5FXmS3RF3IPnqV6JSpsacK9rXE@SYeoI3w4Wk2k9dr2JozEuSKf@RHBRIdwMm10MTzOY9NMlfoUZM@Y6n9dY5O9uT4Oj4fmTl0m6f5DGWtN0/oAwK9AZG@/tSyr@tVpUsXRSLIloB0b04ar3Zf1V89e3n08ujJfrlZb9b7/eUBNQdfNHgnuTXta@ejVq7pCdVtoQpOaSfHmqvtSrluZVcN9KvcIDr4F7d3JQJ31M5XtNwYnabUt1rxqTKpNfeXF1Pq0AMj9R@Nzs6syo@evX6XL5UEgRAtv/O10mb/2/Dz6Ih1u8jv1HgJAyaCV6evTnNgzQlfqaFaFkskMtjZ2W1ecOg/sxDQf6aZZgRwG99huSkVYOn8RQXMRqOxU9/JcT@USrftdEJpsugfm7AYnk3XrfoPfOuZjjsiTrLyh8SzGX0ZRGRVCJoV3MxCu5LNi0xNJou@DQDyOOSLjkBM6P6ZIdMjMFLA50x6A7A58fGpiKV4giclB35sZJJyix3MIgqrlSSBChoG0kEAqobgpIpWR2sRq43I4FosxhTwE9codjCJG4KUC2sgtbjsSSblpAu1M7xk6heLDPyGscXaY0xHrNmsLLkF9qYY8WGIUW1pCaBXHuBGU78sRM28TzMMPRQTDDJ572Ys1ecJL8VtoiykhVF@2hU3XCGUpy0Om13wWtzHoiFd495M6@vpw4fGK683HbSkaSfEa7E4BXN6LloMpBB2ph1Fa3nAbCvsFYvWoDOVPhY9yvy0UwZgoI2YA@k66WmnE3VXIMlve47ytTOQn/ScojaQZ3Lhy85bWe@U5Tl8QWyyLX8FwotFKYadt0Wnpbfhi9tEC5KAqaWotxYPmKHKuWh33vb0QacstWyoWCw@gcYAn0HPLhYHEhC3oXC1Yst@@FAv2t15y1YUCaFeVfee9EJIDIodvG@Kenu@97Y3g/pNEa4dIGNLwDzUW@wDwAf8tUDGrPtS1hmPc2RvDuxNO53Cl3uFLwudra23vbkyHchM/M1y2vHI/ByZz@qIWPgyq1hUJNQ1F/kPrOYHaiEgvAzaB0KWvUxNxmHhSyjx0tFwg6aIvpog3oLEjenoZJk9jUof@KMnCviqEYyXcTEPQ1yg7kFgWFYEzmKTPMsc4XMXViCDM@0oOoXAsujlHVjYn@/tcTHp6NgTKGNQ0dAkOkYW0SflfVwo0BfBBIZv4UtJbjdi62xdYthiP@rk6ZeHBHy26k7G2EncNfeA2oXAN3oIgmP8unzT4h4gEDvs7oBMcOceYMCnkykqBa5USBKCwlhgkJ2oEH20qIOgFhnOxmMWv4rPiwZoaGAgx4NVg9EUsQGDeQ0blvwGtfgB6pMFKTA4lB6zONwDaATygG2wBqQLhpY8fEii23YH/NBdgKJgCPemqCHQCqdA/B6cAg7k8g3oKDDJiABvD7AEYzQWCG3/ywhFcU4iVCi@kVm4k1r5gpdxqz9g4X0oN4mxgX3x4MGbYmc7Ygj@U3cS6kPZzQ@5aCZtkkdHz45fvjh8/uzgBH61ynady2GcUOBao2by3o6VFwB4@GD/0HJoQIKhP9fMP/nIANcA/CxQKXeE74kZkY9efgLrhU8fyxiKD6LHcDFQcDtwmwkmM6DPNgeq65@VLq1zq7T4HieoxGIf6CujFLo/Df4CsoNRTbadBh2mMYcBrmT0URw/vPCKoakZBNF7DZT4TUP0bUo0/HKKUYQwCqP3INADpXhPnJ7A4BpZpud6vnVm0dfHTBiChfr02fKQVafjg8P3F4z0UEeN5hr1crlJyjImtDhRiRPVOLEdJ2pxYidO7MaJepxoRAktxqwxzFqlXq3upMndNFlPk40kuV1OkymG7UqarKbJ7TRZS5Mpte2E2k6d4iW5WJp06IK7BmXadj0uwzhjJ6SZNUCjLWduA6OVFUiovr2SCfTqi5mwQo0IPS0dIVClspPeg/WJYTsi40pmfMiMMruLMmGu4ti6girsoe@DVTqc49tVQOmkJsGgMI4Ds0sM29TBGTBD8FI6T0D/TanJgov9q2YySZmIoaMl91DdhBUc1MEXpZFIfdYUV9YVM2yVtdhYQDdJBJNxwiImGZfNxXg3inF7IS@LdQsNLEp0A0SFQWAfpFzaGZov/NlaktXbSS4gXEtyhSmGt7auFspGpMg7cVU6/1NsnZge81NM2tvgBkTvKaM6sNShGGXeudaa/PfffvNfyfff/vK35Lvf/Pb//MO/x/Tf489/B5@FVBKAX/wSf/4Wf/4j/vwGf36VqUThq03@u2/@Dm7/3X8m3/3pL1nRX/2Ol7cTRFCCWWnNX/8Z/vw5/vwPXq4lgL/@OQPEKrx8wy24ViJA/eIfCQFqiCVB9s3vCeGL4GCIkeb12BgfSNISgkQMPZoaLJezX2Pio9jLUhGc@2J0p6V3RewAKYPc1/HFW@nYA3eGhWGglTZ0Y4KBj1GWG6D/Y6AL4wbqGejb5QicnmhdLkDr/w1pEqGIMJBNg@s7zIZH7Y/azaelCFvkS8AdvjUkQoVpKeEkuAo40G@6ErgKVFz1SFSHmI5E8v0UX@wXTyB8rFlWKMIyKKIV1@5pAxK9jQr@x3VkqrQ4DbHgdPqeMi6K4dMyBBfMzVK3AZXlnCJJjdFCVZphTj3oEqiWyBsFizdUCvIyurTnomFzePRkacDgZwgu5nnWIiWEOoTn74BFSUfwEnpc1UV4xm8E0Cs3qwMuG8y7Dpj/4osveC6TV0Yd8kcixZBpFDMZSZG2WFTJFFUyRcAzw0ltTa1SWeKBThxoF6Xl8OVFE7VYLVUuHDlxPyAbsBZkO3Dy2J4Fk84qamqRF43dKvIMSm3QicZJ36E2p0t4aaUC4Fys01nuy/Woyyswqx21viZKeyFnobc2Y1qokxkUVHrcspSSntMa63pukeAtqLVB8Z6EKuV/ISHlnoR2ancTWu5WrLuAfrN87zY7sZlILHyKjA383MIEhVPjN6B6qTlCjn2aFCVY8hxES57hpUvENW8yg/xS/CzewuvL/MwTeriI@dQNTbY9sO@5sORw0QvOvD1z3Ztmo5dVnjmubwbZqHqLxSY6Aj6xYbhnDsxqMj4TaEUv0sPnjNgzd4vzSjKzRV7oI/ZCTkTNBIWe5@mp5Vjh6Sk4n/ZYSgWIt6qB@3gCh2/yhFSmvpi4tkee6OKzzKF0N07q77JqLyzjXDzyokIBiBwQWNAZpg2LLzLRjXN8Jy0VCTaRxrijRzoMRQmFOHGn7pnpuPi0CtZeQv80xY0M6Z5HeZGJLhMjw1G0iBYNWZeiqh@/d1XycUXUpaR@ZRHBgjBk4i/LGCXrryF3upEcqxbTO3l/fk@y/J7czu/Y8oNwmWeaibs9eH0/0lUxxQCAKRvVu9mQo4fIVthZYCXJxjcEsgr3ZnFkBgZMf8jpAYAeRODqGPRDTu4CuEsY/2yT/G/vwLj64X27jzqzJ1dgb6aH6PvRJVpAn7p1DFME8KcS2p5VcolqP74nrWihQ1d4MuGp4XIw7hAGpueZTpAcSMaI79B562yyokM0E3Ufr2t48i9kcl7Z3EWPT0emrV@ZIzGClDN44xY/N/URtVf3azgaOmr0XPZaSLEsawuuGI0Pp0DNDSqjyxeStFmtGIiVaA8956IcPt0sP7pxt2yacRO0w45qXB8saI4@nUmfifWuvCv2ZInNXmYc2VE2/7Ce/BQfuLlTICAHuq0tanJKVrrNfD4XkybdY0ZIYNXFJmPYeIwRA7dX@/D9RHR3S@kuQ1KpE/fygneyqcet23o8oxWxTjKv5H4qeZfS3VvnMqrGkKUm7NH7TSErmB/ptm0YYhYjy7m1x1xnxSZgHvaY62yYVU7XGNSkJrV0Ib6VrcP8C4mzIPkUrhdw/QyuiBDWoKdMoeK2oV8bb3nRkqnuZbyWKKdnoC@akaKUPUfMQHFxGjdybxKaxkaaxgpNY4FmMgIWSWaAOGOBZNQL2D23dYFtjsMN1hmLcOUOl9vMNnwcV/fxTPhasISmJRPhQmiCQRZMoXkoglEWRkLzMU0EQvOEJs6F5seQSMeW8E5oxsMCAXy4pYl9zI9MON4bQvORKN1w9BX2MV1VaCZ9CjB77JZK5IZtr4LXSLdC3GRX1TRl5lTKBDUmgIuLzeoNZPotw38KGr3yAAq3OqRSoMC4AFmYNDIzBqMD04ZK30gurps@mvHWVLS/ke6hQHmxk9lUQS2ZUXsk5IRFY8QYw1K6@QjXLTx0d4Tmeo6ItrIyu4udiDpoKO3k5tKZO0hPpf7ASKTlPQDObuLYaf24vxZRsA68H59YeROfK@zE5ChHGDUgrWELhfpauKVR2NeLvES9n@2h1T0C7EQlBmG9RNFmbDr4cOibUmKe6y0qCS3F0z4rWwc/0aBE7V2qRq1CNDI3FNPsqGVoGLKDX7qtOZl6yNqCCcLCXnnARlkyL1BbjEWprct4qmzwAQsZmzOiD92ZqLaPoySFY@ZGpnPFpmkorstIUsu1aCahsooB3jM9ZNTTcxkM@36/5WtcE1xw4BERZGomVJh9dd/Df3eZ/x471LEQlgisc6zXT6Wr7vWts@wS53ZKdrUDsVAmj6W1zlFCIRU5rA4ynvlturbi4uNrepmTz4gm2Je8/VhsyZrgDrktry0YLvQS/IvFzHPcmD2vbBbUqkdiX6ix06IipQgPa3jCadq023llDV/XxViCczRc3ruD/cUOznYe4qMN8JdEzkY5vjWfnlMkYzsOO4tOLtipg4tRbMmLLTKZYO7pM5/RaYWMGUenzx8fffrJn8Cku7u7K60eReCohbrpPM7dekyQLFsqMj50TP8UDMZOTFw/3Oo7/IotYcYanAGdntsw9YvGuBTZsow9Xxq7UI/BZiQa4TpPh4G@YJXQ1dFxyrYiuYYgEDMUC3qEJHZvQd4yXa3hqRFqBx7onJ7S6ev0FINzTk@jWQy7JjlG@iEXvXu8ksZrxH9oJY5m2vC3rHADYDZlf7sl2oCLntljcSg5/Ms9yV/CSmrNnNCKgx1wfwiPqJLICLGqSewP/sQ57O/yYHhpBZ@fIZUaPi/DaiE0bnxiJEhMZ4s5OvhWqMBznegP95yzP@5E31EVxFuvlO2Zc6nTMBBGhT7mk@GIBWTF52L0L5@4Dn3fEf6ZGd1hW8ixbGRinqn0xKfSgCXHueWxN1MkoR@BRCtRhmmMFsh4aJtT/OsjoLtrdpOfWdArkyfW2RkoUil6IxoLcHmBf5BEccfKo/hZyxz5jP4NmehdPVFMGH2ZVbQPDOIUFx6WDUhlB7yphgySTb8gWAyTIfhAbJkGaVEo@O7CZZcl63Km7pZ4JS1ek@cOJcS3JZ5iz75jMwX0jg0q72TkTD/vslvT0aEltQOZk8v4uW8uek6/Q88pVYxR80Q@x8dPw2OShU3othE/RorRqNC0Bw41PBgBBgssGlsDDq6DThs9XpO4B9HIcsgHpFqhf6oB6FEvlZIFHOxkbwE7lEFVZJZF90UGhv9gxH@Ah4ncgxzaQqZrWD9WZUzTt/akuky2InTsQAWHMhsC8U0tc1OFpcaDNYS3RL4IWIq8xC9gAvjo9OMBs7yrVcEoSv8X)

Languages that should be tested separately:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse (73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>  (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- DOBELA (109) [local](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/dobelx64/)
- Del|m|t (111) [online](https://tio.run/##S0nNyczNLPkPAsoA)

### Explanation

Del|m|t was suggested by Wheat Wizard.

Del|m|t is installed on tio, but I cannot make it work inside the test driver. It works separately in [bash](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyS/NDlDISU1JzM3s8Qzr6C0hCsnT0E3TUEvE8TRK8nMh8k656ekcmUlliUq6CYXKOjnF5ToQ2UUXGD6S1KLCopSgaSCurL6//9VyoaGhsqVYBgPAA) though.

Del|m|t code that I started with is this (see [table of commands](https://github.com/MistahFiggins/Delimit/wiki/Table-of-Commands)):

```
#z#111#y#y#y#_#
```

Starting and ending delimiters are not needed if this code is run separately.

I didn't want to mess with the first two lines and added Del|m|t on line 6. However, some accidental tokens before line 6 already printed something, so
I used last `!` on line 1 and `x` on line 4 to break them. I used `!` because it seems like all lowercase letters break Japt and all uppercase letters break the funges.

Unsurprisingly, the above code breaks Whirl and Incident. To fix Whirl I added 9 more ones to rotate the ring full circle. Nine ones is the same token as `y`
in Del|m|t, so the code becomes

```
#z#111#y#y#111111111#_#
```

This fixes Incident too. `x`s are for Cubix.

Code for Ruby 1.9.3 switches all generators on for a short period of time in DOBELA, which creates unnecessary dots. Just to be safe, I destroyed the offending dots:
`\"ar_\"[2]==95`.

Comment: *Ahem*.  Del|m|t was suggested by me not Chance. :P Regardless thanks for adding it!  Its been on my bucket list for a while.

Comment: @WheatWizard Sorry, Chance talked about it several times in chat and also he mentioned Del|m|t in [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110860), so I thought it was his idea.

Comment: Hurray! We finially got Del|m|t in the polyglot. Was was able to add it to the test driver once. It requires a particular file name on the input. I'll try to take a look today.

Answer (score 8):

## 114. [Axo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo), 3755 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#1111111B#_#xxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[        _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>4O6O@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # 
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"1015""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3             #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002534 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3853 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tb3ZkuPKkiD2XDD9Qb@gmHkOyeQCgDszk1nFNbnve2aePCAWEiQIIAFwrZPXWi8z3a0xadTTauu5M@o73TYyazPpaWQyG9m0mcw0r/MV9wd0/@DKIwBuuVTV6ZGYSSAQ4eHh4eHh4RHhCI5YY/LHP56hD1lX5c1YVk3SFAyT5HVpKeh@MrUhP7OSEQ4ECQJBJfXxYi4opnFJnJEMKSmcxMMjaaozQZG2gg7RAVLT1bHOzklzwpqkYHCsJhikujC1hUmq4tu5gmR2rk4lH8o4l5QxQJmCrumCiZNDZEeR2fmIZ18khE9L03RINsiMIP8y/8UkOXU@ZxXeAMAImamlsuXki/xRsqLqhoCwcIJhqDph1bSuq/yCQ4SYEwHyINpFSRYMgoNibkjN5pcfBcgzUhdY3gIjRFUnURZyPpNJieQ0jRzJ7MTPkbIEsDk6RgqoruQW0s9IQ50Lx0QZpCIIPGloAieJEodLJYW1KSiGpCqGn5S4GbmSZJnkBRkyHEjhvICMXBhHUVbBfoJXCRI@nPaC8P3TuQAwirCrvKCxOq68ijgDnNjxYKWzmgZEAutaQLgpzaFtJdNpkAJrSEh2IIshKDzmm7aXKpVkleNakkuJJVmgd6Fj3Iagm1A9P8ZLTgRdAJTsvnFdK10ygQWIrUmyLrA62dYFwX0qYydFQmEqKsFEFfHjZru@dmZrOSc0n5XDz2omcaYH240iwZL@BHn@eAXfhMNxRWSrGfLL@T0KW1IFTazpLtZNJn5DGtT9vQDfNTOixvozAVgJ4IpMUqpmUqxPAwJ9JhBIsSiIQr5lwK/JRwWT1y/a4kioLCgeWoMsKGTXi2vGLXQddZsDU9kZVFpWlTHwEyqrLxTED4WM0NAEnAqC7yWFJXBNVaw2UleYw@2JBI1moCZhR8AglkO8t7o@Zih0fpA9m6O7cg1VXmA4yGmYSACBK5AVYSyIZJcUWUlGWSAdobKo1gVjIZsoz0LhUctD7xZ4P7kjg1N5BDRXl1AcC0hxBPSh@VHPw0QBMDSEiquKkn7/L/8NPx4DniTHqTpvi2uX5FUOKykWEwvdn0QCqyqsjMkCOC8q3coOBSxZWeJZExWvbOwiMBG41JW6kHlShQL1lQRda8IuoTuKosCZgiXklmbzknN2ZukLyZJcqPicHUHD4gJw2bjaPvJzGlqJEyyR8c0XphgjfVqWdBrUT65Pl65PH@8FoM3td1@cU9T4CuTNf4Gj4Mn5NcHpJg/tiaSnLamoH8naZAFaA1IUQwN9oiNmcixUx0BqxQRt7yVHmNFYF4Go4066Epy6QI6gZ@8qhmXEkgGU34d6ro3h0KY7uFMRE/gjCQPpBCEzjVdqQlZXUDCmDSlSkGkFFc6OWSjKtCuUtCpklYhjTqs2U0DSEbaRQMZ8IwlaB8kBKBu7MY7qCODBgAUD2KzWO@oUc3YDWDhLSR9akpREaOQ5yK2@ITkBdQboFYKl6VAhCywYBox0aMyjfYFw@BuNb@pU0jcE7bGlvtrGqPIvmjlJisKKlFllvGDHaLBVIAvLcYJm2j0IamKY0EdeKkIc6bO1ut@YEOefX5aNtZut74/KQNrHaj1bR7NI7O0R1ydDLydZ21wgeUmH/iJvXpYOAMsXhTt@RiAnBPzseIeE3dAEQiasBW5hQncDQV5NJG4CsouoU6wOa2nHl8VD1HHpoHJ84r5oRAxz82OA8FP7KETGuyh8qEVf4wGtj1DdnETgxj@O@Dpm1pi/gVjdkwga6ijWT7F@kD2baTCet5AtAepvN3jjnrU3MPb8BAZDV4duCsIyMU3NuAR1I5mTxcgPzUq19U3BrCmoZSlT30imaoVHsjqi5qwBnYnalUBxi5G0flEjHLdn@NQgljCMiwaZAP3/tAARcTlFw@m@wvFpBHyU5MBDK0ZhXR0AiIH8wCmXaPiRCZYDDdDaKJzL4cdy74ce4vCSDtTLHG4IoFx7vqTVOVIZZA8PL8heSOmgZkRQLYS2MSfABx9HOtiEqgmKy3kilE43LtDlvsLWgdPpn6qS4vri/Pjxo/PSeeP0QugThK5R6BMKeSD0CYd8OITg/CiEc3hxCKXe4Rwo7sH5fLfDvHY/oGZbIxNoK2ku9u7yMvjgZe8Y@x5AdzfoJVBDAO1DN8DjdCcSKOh2O25WUFH/SLRq37Q4y2NpaArKmBDWmqqbZLWWyT7Wk@18wkEtDJ2SpRGlwID4OIfuBiaw4438YMvuskOwqapmAjcYisfQOQCyzXLCVBfQQcF8leaSWcBGs6wg0T402i41DeVaCArHJrKoq/O9ejEIgZuopOM86ECm3ck8wq9tdqkhlLqwpxFH8VEUP0ezAD9HjDmO9KnW4z4Sl//G9MFGEEEIeHUkyOtIyCfIot9cb/2oK0VChHUjffx7EG/kJdbbtzIQJvQL31p8kcDu5ixtUMZlsAbJsmTgmdYxy4i98NwTDku4g6dq1oFSLkkrLWCZskvo2DBoaJu3TQzHMTKcAXg@U5FGOYQeaT8TPkEBE6PXOUXJmODLCeiesB1Zr1NwbmM@EvHlzTpZNgIYHGgKhThTRAY4MlNUFaZbKww2VxXVIgU4Jiks1cQ3Pwwtb9FzqsFPiBkJ4gKMcmokKSj8DTBfPIYhxdFIeg8U@IJI393fANMXo7fYBjI2eTXIkyeMNxe6KQu8ff8vf8pDA7xungm7McDan@0Dj8A31FQ@8d3WsrOiB3x5u2UxzHQhSyxmAw59CyXHIoOflfeBt1EjrUX6fBNWh8bd7BoXhBNdYAT6ipxZlOuCvOCF3f3tQjCLT00JK7cizXGN4I7sIjzUvJP9hSFk5UcTJl1WWR5jsSayknBobatdhDU7hspRR4rJr4@@g86dvUIeZq4w1psL64omq99qV0lD36/1VxuSDrMjRqBUgx1J73ARERF5T66t7oLGZp8oszMr@IiCb1fVqowujWFmvLu/BwbWIhj0GssJ1Arf3lUxysLQrKZAoa/g02Xr@h7IbgVsH3gPEKop48uvETssCBz0DUQqWizyHbFIesFUmR1tkP0y@fXygwocezykD9RLgvN46CAaOfdzucOylKa9nx8Ntzh/PP52bmsFCyPgVJh2C9/qszDuSHNW9gX4o@C7Knhn7x1Cb4BO2SULlqDMGiAgps1mYQnNgi9fE1o0lHALmdUPoa@I7IGc3ZT9vVnfIY8mcaos2ZK5e3hPF740wQ9o0NokvhyyoqfX/OXB6kXDtG8fertDq5yJZl7vyNF3qCdr0oOmlUeC4Vff4x2nrtD33d47UZeCdX17yNq@SdV3qB@fjCUDZlKvs/Pct8QVLSrhy9tcnL1JlcnJb8ZfkhVV1WHWa5ABP40MHAWvhMKALcvWxK5dqL0v04YkqwbZwtev8QKsa8Owrm9L8zHbJFbxcROrj@3Db2d7kyg8vJFJfH2ncVl5rMqR2Jhi4fKuBCx0EWl5@/69Gm6voRjmmxpqb@6oCmPf31XtM/j/lnCg1RTQ5RIydPbBr1hRb6kze873fgVhYoBWz96uXI6O4Zx@ypoSvdcAOjdZsZvd/Z8werzH3d3ooW2wsQzWHMoQj0HA1C0D@p9SWujrpfHfp6NeoY1@qxJHjTuTBdDY@PqqSckAzfzKHAxNf7/GEuWFsBDe1CC10VQAsfma7vh@omi7Guf2ogAFzEPbXnuorT0V/C6q0XiOnr6qcFhZgk7@TWvmTVWjgYWtoRl0HQJ1FHidcawstJPGPeJdc6E0v865ibbr2Sp/QiRK@bUaKfZtm@nEDDcE/H1bgVyiHViY8KpzsCGU72h/Gyleb7GuJ4hxzAHzVEJLOfpX8V6S@0U@sF/BHoFWlWaGD60HfZ/iCbw3U8fA8TjMxRTB3KDre9x@S5GOVFX@Na0D@pSXkJkGxifa//1WK12Src18BJYbd1iB/I4W2E0TgVtoSvxuw9YBpfmdOIOvF9C@MkodLae9WfKtKt9c33yj0Zuo7zL@mD/6VcDdqhe1C7zTBTGyuD/4PeaPtrNp8WIjWqC0liQP@9RnL9SLtgHGSLzP4CbCXMCPXzHoWX66MHa3d4HWKvq@TrbXWfG27n6fxfDa@9EQJ@n27qOx3@I/KyicLuBdl93CPnmG9oIWc5h8mKruJzGcy8V6PG43YWVC9utYAbAdFN5kRftc1v6tQcKswsSwkkje3ZHnX9aX9CXzTCZIx6WDfHiwsOIdl@xaw7ujTSvr3Tn7kDh3@nzOc@e9cknSTgwqyGBOvAnKnsCJEr5ZdB6qTirsHG@tofCuplfW/h1Y@WjTdsIqvCyQHegfeO6j6tYulLXV2UbLXf/5H3h7L3ssQCXnkgHDx1hB/hfqXJioq09WuXbpSU1j0V44wgEzfNnaAPOlk6SxkkyQCLyFDZOQTq4ds/cfbc8QeKgjRXREhdWoqGsCDaxpNZpFDa8KlvDaBe9z7SoF07zFXCFXEm9ODD@Y7Aon4P3N/aI4hBCYYuoqEn4vWSB5AS038IgwLI@yqs7w6j2i5D//g7XrCokSEiEU3hWP3QCOSiRRH8NbnRynLoDqHZKtoKs2iAsxGSarC6TJoesJVryb5CYs3g4GSfTtNkNRMdaGaDrZIn1Z0oncWNCuzZUkus6TzdvuHf2Q@A05p4T/8qeU@4vNN8cPvihjOLzkDuTqGcnVcTINyYdUJ@k4XzvsaiGHCewfsBcq20vJhcK4uXabm3Psa4HlTljhzU28g60gJY@cGBQD@gc8ujFqq9Mkzl0LS6/4WiYZRr4@ArAEQpZ3Bom8Z9BGHcpyviZ/ISdIVnwcyYRpeLIYIqO94XkitVssDh4v61MZYbTAq1vLgD8QTODqnD8mQOeikC7wKvIeuPvpfvVAGTuu3N@vf6ADa2CbqgP4jxTqOdlq5su5/4b@5RcDDHiH49l5Ze1vQPc@/1Iv1LOtdrLdaQEbn61anuVUfc4eVAQSAk2GqdVElbE7BvBDlwTj22rjA9YbxAcb0OUiz1nyGkxaEjTUh71isdnq8DnOraCVhjXJPu1Foq0@RIm0VR1Zx61tN6zTOFZz3p0AIOZBn1yAXt0RD4Lz5Q11havjIBNQIR9UCIPvCd4/vVWx01QMbzH8E3oGptvVOIbCVT1AvQ2E6moB23RbMBaRb1bi@f8jyjUYR75NOYL6FuUATHyr9KOCc8lCudPMvi77qFgb5hXIXkKOPOCyazDhQA@KWMKRl8VOblTbS2anGEDvT6y9dFY@qDaDXEqGNJIFLEkiUswy9G3UKfAas4E6N4n0iJ9MygYoUp4HzTDamEixgEb1481Fa4fRp5COM2CAfz/OeUkHgWCNxGtvCVAcKzBBuZ@tzOcYDmM23nI4uheo3//Lf2M5Gd2bEP5zOyxC@F9Y4Z8oxKDXXikWjXvWILZ0C3XSgNHKqvicXR/VCQ0YaECSFJh6SnPg4BIzBIFbxB7qe8DjuusCP6ERgJlI8yFlh8sT9AcXclO4pCg0vo9VWfTjnSlhDe0AuhJ7LTwtkM8X6GcqEo6EGAqI9C13CH2ShdCnWQjd7ksQIWIpaYmfRxx5fX1NOgyYigiJyJXFSOqc/Sno@HlP6DnAEpYpcEdCHshyyAFpN3Y21znrYdwoK@qFTsZJPlzBKG@1CwwULhwAEDeKVmx@OGAkUm1WQaMrwtrESnWzM3HAvlDwbrVgef7tEPkAkYXb7SBeye5hywPtBx9Js/@4GRw9BNZCYJeOt0Tn7ify3rxXHmwXNRIE5t@9IUgKhP/iDb@1vfQkX7unuV46l6HakJ9bioo2wXJALekKUIEgxUTcRz3FYaMCelG/@AVQQk@AnsUJ0lTVjGQ6WyjW6q1X7lUY0vkSzEk6b6499z6/9@5hH3C@kPodU1M5qlVJ5XasPKbqMJtEEIcp5Usy3yrtJaXvlN6z9ptel40TXhXE0N@LGM9HfTm86vIa@yGVOgJMW@vhr0p1ub883z1c39wrZ6@K/@UtZ8gz/wUSLgjdG9gV0km@oXMKu120NnIoN/w7v4yA4@Dpu/fssJ4P0e87Xe3d0w@uV7v9OuR4FbiBaeOSUhayTPjf2cmDuvspqyjsdWQRtqMXdM2OVAaReiiQI17thhxTQ9p1ee1JDzn3rYOYVLNmh9gDlFVgYqBLnAVtYAVtzSGxuyLMIgrmYeIBkxm0XoDnVxs8lwBVsd9d4CW8C8XqOy@afUpLmEu@9o4epDgOjlSgyJCD0ATqJkujKzZxtyb3bilf87HyG5osmS7k3LT2ozka1MblRhVgrmUB@UZdxx9sRyxy5y/lwS5X9QXwq65q5GFenBF2oSZMjcjMApCDGAhkcTEHOBHfmgIaJQSyqvogM/DRuSPiDkpx2XXwz/kwlO6fCGteGsNI43J7QSX9wDAHZy3W7YH5rBP0sMWqW7RtcsyYX@VgdsQx9o71SwovrF3OldN9@YC4A/HOVW/pdDteyQD2crNd3viX7m47ZcGadq89uIq9UAjx@F4RnPadeNw/MQjkLwTWPZTYMvUyBGEMdYlzViNdC@wvaJB@Ej@67l2K1zB1N@m7QePZilRIjwfPC@CGE/wkzinikCSj9RgXctJ2UQloZxRrKDy6bSWNvGP8/gcI40Lc5Dma0qfB3ECTYTcBRiRkucRoYQCGv0tE0QpmQIgi636OiyXQfFwHqDeTcUceT3AHBF7gWpM3P5IHbXDogRZX4/FLuzVO1WGcBLG4fkNjANo31NzO4gT@2k4fwDWkxAAqDTM9CRTK55KgKNBfXSAzc@idJLsAIdPd3t17PN69//EZLuHMIjFve5EAoWcnijjr/CKrYM@cU1d4Wnn1DOP@z/do4BftoX9D/Qnlp66@uM7lxIYCY8x94zqfJBhP8MLjOVcuXOcKMkd@/BHNRp/Pwdp59Dv8jjUA@c5l9xXIM1hHiXPl6py9dp3zicAFzgGPHo/7C2T4jUH5v5yzz9T5j2BNeCFGt3qn69xwo@5A@/3MM9CHesg55QWZ@eJykI418uRGxZ9LHg@iwX/@iAj4DXXf8uBx5b5F4fnvlW3kUuP5To2c2ir7lnj1apHFQDv6cq/Rw9gp0FpPfNwBI6/D3dLpG2lv2Ud//OMZE4GZ3qdI0KV@CgQ/XpyRZ58d1IVDd3y5zyyvnHesGPA/PdRn9Xrffe9ynqVrDibkgNr8dEVeUMQZdUH/EqWon3/@GaxP8u7Gf@N/cN/5nA93rvVNNHpx5Y3ELryfvYzTe3VGygzNMG5XIOCmyPsWeR9l2QtPKPBZuZIkSTN4Hr7qBL0hAZZYAknJB/i4mLrTGQ46Wz8hF9dPnz7CH/6Hz/4RXT/iGDsag7z@fHSTrqc1cXbzYf1P@VAME7hHM7Zg5OPnD1BlwYM/l5ef8TyGdERjDlX9/E52H/oQZ78hzrZnDMOcbeCPsT6ps8czC4g4@/n6Z@IMzP2zm5uH52eP787/k8fvf3zw@DzXd9fX/pub9Y3v4eZuN7d9JImzL8TZ@pk4Czig/e4viLPE@rqJSbvL3Fg0ep5s8DKEr30Pd1q9nE22st7Ate8skEumvYFWJ3XGwFP48IgSg@ixmU1map22N2Dlui10s506xBsPjzehWqT2@bPHD7X77L95uANafvDceBKmaZLDxws/@fXP4xsh65E4y9ysO5TvGkgu2zFNXI7vHp7u3VDaL8TZ3dmd61PgU4CW6SXNzJhZRa0d/ms1iJfW9FTV6Qk9YXhg95oWOvSG3qzpuVpjeAgK8EfPISjR4poe0wqtMMwJnvf/5zW1UlMBlQrZzDVtIqy0CPdxrVYBZCIUPIU/iaYRfWt6Cf@0bDX9T480Sbrp@3vijnT8LEBn8jNOP@30R5xO6SEc0Z6@PAciT3d4qA3HH@6EtWQ@OEiv8/H@Lh6POx@uzijj/p6y9IsjEHJcIZDn58fHTLKdfHyk0MrD@vrc89nj@wyfxI3n2r59OuNvEEP91x/vCadr1ev10Le3Wq6sEA5Ycb194vEDDsBn@U7e08A7IuBy3YUfvjy73e4P984rp1UTl0sA@9HlYO7XAZEMOLBZFgelzATR0B8Ju29uImF4jsTcPheNUq0M9w5N0@4dfjxN9eOd2EQiqevsBpmmrpAbxoV7B6s/3jvuAg@JRDyM8gZ98RCp6r540O1wu39irq/tIgJuiHY41w5Vd5Jfno//XF@er13440Z/bjeKtK83bhcku8PwtP7iWl@7rl0oDqJQri/PNyiI4b5A6M7lfnA/P1txcHW5ry2cN25gHJqL///0rxqkoZHOs@czNLQrZCjshpm@4A5FXDFP3P5LfITKuBxBZxDq6HCyzru7zxfBi2jo7tPDxcOF6/rCf3F/83Ci7dzOMxKEeieECeYM8ZA48181HUzA4URCeYXWt1VZ8Msw7w7Gr06lwvnounj5iTFxz4Xn891FPG6VfXHxy0foP4AOCnPA5wwEmXSR1zfXe@k6oHTfwPcLaTMcws9fQOCsNLAUXPZC9v39mqYx/NUocf7ljH2@wujJZ4fz6kRuMXqX8wrvcDi@OM5Z/Y55cDw7zr@MnpFFdcG48cAdDl1dXYSscDR2BQMoc2Gn0JBiByFBMFgOd2AYMpFkOYHlbqhUYiSMJRh8tBMeecLhMBWA6/qHSDawJq7QToC17eDwOayORMbiGOEZaRhxAoz2ETT8iozSMCmTZVYnVVH8aMXD7IMcCQIYgIIsozU0ZJyDjSrzK5gQfiTOQOGAaQrJ8JnXWWEhCKvFYiXsP2nJuGSnU5hb4s8ffvc3/wy@/wDfv7Tuf/m/xcPo@off/Y//y@//9u8g8j/B9/@E73/8w@/@9Z9aX/z8j/D9v47i/tH@HsFZXwJw/Xd/@N1f/f0ffvcvfgvf/9n@/vbl9/d//R@s///b/kPBv/v9X/8julgPgOtv/uL3//rPgMS/RuF/DmH4t6P/3A4exVrBP98FId@/fQH8F3/43b/6ezv8Z8cgR/GQ9c8h/m@P4v@cIFBjfiTDUa/X7/fDBd29@IPv/vOfdiDM@6PsGUlU0DpenLF2NSWUBUK6ECfyIAdz9M4MernSRDYdzPVowo@kJhCIx8KxeDAQ88bisVCYiYTDXibgZaKxaJz2gjUXYyKxcJzxxkLxYCgUintJJhCOR8H2V3hJpCgwRBiHg8QBSeGQp/s1emVA9U9uiDNeEGFC9YFcu3j3hzN@F0EuYqQjGLunSYc153ORbvILGv1cpAFTf6DcRXsXoPPDnxYxRyTquLyAu@OTIwjBtYukndB1Hc57h8N9F3/45IiGHZdgO/qcPzKfwEKLwzwwGnVA13ZAFcIOR4QMRB2OIUi7MPY5yfUnx9UzkLzjxb4yJAyTfj8JX7DiULqWsOhxOeIuEveL@L3D0hpWF3S6nM5owOl0O68AyUfScdQq7itUOaibVbUdgYgmIDAOw92VLpgLXXHFfaCCSV/cffVskfTfHNGkz2Dmyepo9oeLvCQdkbgDRQPItSuOy7oJjy4uvYzP@5mwFEKEIc6eCR7584bi5FX8ClmQMGhd39jUlchNdOzJH9F7RZw7EcXO4AvhwnuMJAl2mC@ohtSz8/NzMF/bN46go@Z/vKZs8/OGwnbn/c2VJxFKe7AV59/ZuTfIeH71CYUIXUCbfTx6Wd6yCWJhxJcxaZwBuivPP@Xjh3ITgJS4QqOF40yzxqsNMt7Je4vW69@cYbuBrH/ZbeYsFLwydVlBzcZetvBbE3cPpPs3VUn@Egv6bvA8zgXNREJDPbfiP0V/iv1U6dQ6tdxn@jJ2Gbu/f238EmfGL241zPxGKV6dXWrOYAhx@D5xZtWXibrPbgJRv8Fuzh5sLwVXKAryQ8IzHjQCzJmILLCDofbKQDsKvfG8Ws7xJAFIif0JPx5LgT@p/PzLOUU5nSTJnEd@47u2/q/hkq5ZNDgiYYcbuXcYPz3@9HgGIwPpCISRhHso0lb@xyPl@kLBf8KFgf8E4RBhwOPuCaUL7guY7vcDoIHi8Ugsckb8kaK@ti4LqfuFClGACfxi/tZKRVKXKixaxVH2qxUQqCy2gg536EeGKvF7VUUiXYWW4pCyOo6z9ddRFD4J4jRuY1DI9wLFgh5HZwZwaGmMFJHOcCG7x8S7euQFOocD@Zy4iS/EB8C14EzstgGXK4L4gHYp0aNrB@clfzRMN9rtod3Ehw@WlgBgv2E@IuQokx3pY66IZwKxh@V5g0SLSHjzxnJUYdH@oKpZ7mTyhrQyGVjLEoi2C@xjgso9IviCFC0qoDYXJC4RU44qZxX/wQIbLURESq5QzkIeMkGKeDHSzu3QR@iVWVy9j6LbLpykIQphQeCYUxgcAQI6iHRh3O458obhXBjSQzIoXcSLmgAFo5AXU@IlRTvjHXp8gOwIvcjJqgGIrdJdVg3Ii0e7WLsONj24EsBCVDussFGA1cec12499ILV3QOMULv9fBdKJa/JgHu/A23jgsawDkvBGbk5bwkOfhfZZjPGxjx4oWmvrM1j1x7Ojjkw6pm4ML3zK6uptCui5OLcX9Ci19Vv5j/@yP2k3c0frtzzhInuHs8cxo@ZS7JALszEPAHiod1JD1fmnccjPSTm7pILPcPQlKABWLSYbbjtukHNlQTQghbGDbd3e6f4fqM8eHN3igdIXngvhomtl03Q3jV8pQTjlb1PCcauB5RpJrYe5Yq9hi9afzvZoIex1MNene7ZQ5aZS05s79iHBPBDhoweTw4qA3Qad7LH8@CGwmVIfJ3xSv7xR9Yj36yvZJ/PjaB@Cn7K3ZkQePAk0POli71ef9reLSD/pQvuCShGdgPxkM/m9fOedqDvCnhstemBdIvGNSJvDeTNE4mL4aeL4UXi48ft3do3f/Ba7L@kD9KAiF8j4g9UgxheDN3kC5bguYjL8YN0@YP/wiAdXsnjASZ7taOcFoUXQ0jRYEC0qX5G@hKfmLFb20USZm/WW@8441c38VYNOgEHuSCpKA55DUHepMFJkg1uuXtpksCjV2YkwwuzB8XHYgiUZp8pgxLv158@Ebui7Z1kKBkpl5FAsshZCx/goKOZET6fyOB0CZ2V83X9@pYa3uncvd3YKgyzJNiowchRd8WqCXc4Q@fuEAhSA1/o5ytLY1n@A6BssPYAGKw9EJwPaRHEJFtP2JAJOxHZpHYDQS6kJ0TLCRm9@Wsg/QTq7dDzQYVYZEBnfoMMyTtNYN0E8iRBiJSucXkQgK5CfIBKIBpQHaQH8gYUGfnjj6T9eJ0AuzuKxgIEhuCmHgYBvaIUCv8OSgEHonIKMor0IS4EaPuAUpDby0lBof@6gmzXMRdk8Ey9lgeZP9B3eNEeimF5TCK@uS0yUFt8@DAFE9ImCP6x/Qz5Ie35j2f2cH9JpmuVeqedbVaSLbgygVCMOCPtMf5yf5zMq3MpNHTexEhSsI8HxzYZYVDkwH4BaxBESuXR8UU8WeyUYX5UzXjR@xTAeuSBJ@AB9XKPSTDwW@qGX9XH1EqaSdTpSWSQyXInwYee@fDCPxg1iBw8OMsHP86DG6eBZm4wmNtO4CcnX80Fw7CP2/DtDsDCh3xhj9Y5csyEXmgfz4F36nabDXhrCy0KePGGqS6NJXyq0cRCcJIfn6RgWtlx/yDQsRo8a7JIool4jKYvSdqLAswuENgFgrtAaBcI7wKRXSC6C8R2gbgdYHaYGQszE4gFg5FDMHoIxg7B@D4Yog/BA4ZQ4BAMHoKhQzB8CB5KC@1Li8QwXvJsx03cdQUdpTGh2C4NeYsrJo4MAxrmZWQICA28goTsoVeRUF7sNBJm5HZBBaqGgAKByOEZtM8ONuGyqPJadHitkq0nOxLGKsKa/WCBzeo6aKXsGh36A0LnviSRnx1BgNolOVlgwRgQTLBSEjmQf8F9aflr65vL/SAlIAwJZv8M2QWYskIedNQfaYvPG8mBt5ItbIE3sVlu@eSeMUeOhjaRFpWXpy6EGGPoJO4Y60ekYBFH34EIWBCoDQ5UykdltvXFm0UGv17kCcI3i3xFlIU3/FYuxBsXRp7YZcXjP8aW2JVn2SkCbm0wA@zj87AMvGhQ5Lif@MJcOv7wu9/@r@QffvdXf0f@/m//7v/5j/8DCv8HdPnfwWYhA3uAv/wrdPm36PI/ocvfostfH2XC8MFLx@9/@@/g8b//9@Tv/9lfWUn/6u8d3tAeEaSgqEPOv/nn6PJn6PJ/OLzhPeDf/IUFiLI4vM/EiWnlAqi//E8kCaUhLHtkv/0HknR4wMBw2ZJ3Z/XxB7f7BYI9G@5w6OFlunXlJjpiO@32OACv/cQcnjyoAdxHyHUWnQd36Htgzlj@LUhLcyw3Qb6kdpRqIPuHQyaMavjHIG8rHowee/XACbX/b8lL0ulBMBCN31dIWDrcrr9db8chFcF6HBRQh87IsVGhsHtPCUxvCZBvPBPYGH40bcEzUsaSEZu/VXTe5G4AcewkSzJdjJuwy9rlhkkPaR@SBv@HqS4SWjQMWf7@@Pg8wnaLZI4KPFE3L5oNSnkZA1PGg1fycVYcIcw1aBLItuc3Yix6wFzwvkR3aDm722RruRcdBn1GYGLOjjXSvqAE6XB8AxZx2oZ3I4sreApv0WsD3NGXwQfi2D/6LWBHv993EEdxNJIhnXdhDEeVslTGPok5TQocJQWOkoBmCyfWNeFA4AUNeOBAetH90iP8VEWdZjsIF@o5u3ZAZMBc0Foo9IrywpgkXqPGGvlU2b1GfoSSeUjY/eRewTrnhnS4X2UAnKd5Ei/b8m3U9CuY1w31dk7E7ZOYk9Z6H9NJnqNOgblHvOTSvuWY@Fstd1rgV1AzD57vLChA/1cW5PvOgiLhbxf0sllR3hP07/P322pnpyb2Gv6AzOr4ZycDFBoafwuid1BHiGIdB11umPIk7SnPaKWSrjcO2IN4avdC5cmpevrRa5ZoElNVTcFaHvisqTDlUJEVfHSo61tnJdtnqI4VVReM4xcVJMvpU3Gil2A4dazAqOZFL3ZK9vmO6NUt683J03FlP7LZVmjaOicWobYYhSzPx0dJkczHRzA@ZdF9YCB69HPIE89JoANmIXSU37U3bWuaS0UvpJvub@PE9q6VrS1xM1dNsxOdUEiShAkdJ8gw@SInLDdDRyVjlqAq4tcGkEU6Ml1uxMSJOlfHgqKiF4BQ7hfoCwfciCBW0zAtXpL1ktwRRfYk2sV5WbedtfSrs5KlgIt17/MHThGcMMNL6i95jDirv1Hc47vFWdl25bV@Pb2tY3pbX6dXlHTDfEkzjkSrPej@64oOug4YAPBARvDbZHjt9/JekXNCyj4aHVxpZfhuEnnB4GD4Q5QmATRpg/tFkA/v/smApz3h3ff4//UG3GXPfm/zYWO2tQF9M88i2w9P0Qz87rTCCS4AL7iR7nld3F60M99Zlj3RwTM8L@nAiktBDp3QMTVNUIz9BuwO8TdkXhpPXskQjkSyj@5v0KQvveQs8H4TZR55QWY3Au@yIb1HeHc1bgosj/XV91UcKTqs9FTrtFIX7WVOTDHseI@BLt8RGda7dLvfFysLRNpLD96MwxQW3ucfXrh7qZrRImjC2gNRddCgZ/iFV/yasbbRNtbLOrJ1xratR63xx2rJKnqH6ZsMAT7gZW0X4z0U6/6a@my69lX6jhFhD@s/rTLyx99hRB7xr9vw17Ho2zXFqwz7TIldK59YJ@@1uPS1Fj@Sip1MWlbJ94nkt4Tuu2XuSNQsZAcVlv51Q8grzGlWljnOdYzRivlqi6nKK52A4lCLqco7o8rjGwp1nxNrOhMdqJew7As3IUGwAPcl3LtwRwhhDvpoCdSubsiu3S154ZQ5qx1ZLXbMHYds0SMuuo/3EY@giF0YLeQ@78vk3i2Te1Umd1LmvgecFnkERHAnRdqtgJrna00gC6L5jnZGSWjmDrevqW34KCqro73XL07JeSl5SefSeQkK2Sk4L7MuUMpO3nmZwQHDednCgZnzsgSBQ99y/uK83HULBKDDIw58RvG2CkfPnPMy7XI/E/iXFXbl@p2X@zYFmE/WI@bIs7W8OrJ3/dX9qqogeC2j0ksiiTHgpqJq3T148ZeGfwxqnyIBiR8TZOACA6MJyMmgcTRiWOXAsOHHB@W73ho@LndLU/b6xmENBdI9iaNFFSQlC6yPnGfOU2VkEYZS8eIj3IFApDcv36aIZF7NzL5Fjl06SChu5NPyMff82B7gXTj9DoCPF3HkQ/5de52isBrw@@hEmd@j8xU5u@IwRcgZwP0GWYipPzu/UinU1qe02K1/3EKv1whQI/p2IFYrYbRHOh1sOGSb4sI0VTsVEpyKdvuk4zzoY3dKJL0vsmGtYPfMd5JxtF0zpBiOO7/7a9U5yodIO1FBKPGOfrB62X5cwLoYJR103ZGlanU@IOFI5/D4bUYBiW3GDmI4S9148Vjx3jC0y2sViTXXqZqEzH7k0b5gTav0w74M8nP/ddPXXU4wwYFGhOAo574US7@qv8J@Vy37fWdQ75jwooC3DOu3h9LX5vVXR9kXlMuHYl83IEr0khn3m8bRvoQDy2F2cGSZf03WXpn46IRly8i3Ct1jf2Ht79i2nxN8g28v5xYWLmQl6MvTyBlamJ0F3mfUa4tEXvp3RosflWTjsSq@p/RQta/TalX8rSZGKWiMhtuvbmD9tIGPGw/hwxXQX7Dc6uXoxxzwPsW@b6M19aOdC2vXQUVeYvuzQo4iQd1j/7W9ixZE1B6bmVq1PIBBNxqNul9vRaBeC3kP4zjx1W2C/bQl4EVvc@NfKEK@ExNVNz/eK47XLmU4AowBFu/bWOJn93G3rcuO9PmLvgv5LNgjjtq4ZoduwJ5oJWTqsGjIlmy@msAQwXRdsDaSnXkL/Pbi2RraNULSgTZ0Hh/x8PX4iJxzHh/tUQw1zX4b6Y9nu18KOPhr7H7/Z@fN9M6vsaEFgMXc@kkhewHOfhnS8kM5Qz8otf8tt32uhWJKO2cHtD6Etqj2nhGuIOO2fodqF2P9XBRIqiuAXhgiA2H0gpCVC0GjhU/sWmmX89EydNBBW4amKvbvSc2s3xzDx34Zu6VXTPZCWbHYDcQqBb/XdESR5ZC12xfDP8ijKvgIKfTrR6xiLSHveOMlhbEf7/gE4jDlmEmaddjH3vXDcONMmGDsowU8HsnCHP0oDsjuG6vJFQlaZZKTxmMQJMo@2c5ycGmj38nxqaIvffh9vC7@aSP7@CPbJwyfD2avAwM7XSdvIRtkIALWVNwLnD18gbHITYZEbxrT2EkLQ8E3CreoFYx5j/J@dG3cp3dm93EjfB9dj6hlf7FGCmgdGUReOeIz/vxyvDRtb1piPXC0c7l7oZ6wD0BI4H1KP/JR01yOM8fumAEUtNwmWJnbvZ/rQm@GXxIfFKx4kAcYyVm@NWDgKshow9tr7r1LqkL@QAYD@Gc3oDxspeJiAYe1s3eCHdIgKyLW8u6zFYzjB97xA9pMJD6cIV1oyRrKvxNlFMYHIR1kmfxoo7M2VFBXtrrA7iF89BCEqcaHNwr@6HJ4AIvH4XacYAJ4e/fjg6V5X2cFpej@I9XmI72cmkwm23NGb94mx8lJsjmA5xRd9vSmoSxFZfMyn8wURptbNdpeigG6PWikRkFPPcqvNSk/T@e1LCGFBnPPMLiO50PbcDqYTnJ0X7wti6Foui/2DSEpC3FqOZ01eKGpjRjdkErVSrW5pXKdRnfcmIrDXm8aVVqE1hymxo210Ij1lGW3Ey8YDaGbrpqz6tRcMJtatBfprBQj1W2nJsVNYTVbFyLqQAqnG0K0K2r5FbcJa1y@QwyX7Umkld/M4syc3yTTBj@IejzUIJ0ax/IcPxSLrXSJH@vhUXjWirPB5bwoaptJKa88lafp1pLzaNNcIbIklHphuRJCvdlIzivDZrc7yqTqqxljDDV@GupVFuYopkeCwUVSmExD4cLC1GPlVLIUNTPJQjcn97vmcNON1Qkzb7ajnSIXlz3LmskFF5kOZdDddVEqtVaRfKCt5pWiXJjWZ7eL27qsLWaZkFRrz0P6uJ8bqYFAvtFa5gdlQg8Ve4NYcxqIZbg1R5XCqjoPtuPVsl5ZL1JPNaGX5lopYRShU@F@lplWahuutiw3m7261uvMo0aJkYc5ekrU@lwrmZrlyvMY065uCrHbQmuRThfWy1FAHKvJBd8LVvqRVbkqFHoNKphnF2bFI6VrMjUtFo1Nt1Mq9KvGELp1pSiFxM061U3p4lMmbVSaZaqqzyat0FThtW5USqtcsV4ImYVZMr/qDeOF1EwQ66OZOmv35N7ClDJTKkds0rNGZySsctJ2xWZD5W6DmmabnBlNjoMtaiqKo5lcM7bj2/J23FqMxny8dktnhKcSn@qGm1mNqeSMUFXZEIN2SpS2zYbIzOrxfGE4yialihJO1wWtfptfrgOBgSTWV@Ets@5PcyFpzYXoci3Vr3gaxUDTU/akUnU1WBsTgUzutjcOlzxqTthSZZF9iqY9@mIRWmcW6JeVyh1F1udhmY7l2p5J1NB78UplNTIK/Wa6x8nb2LAym0WGTaK/LBiqHogVc8k4VZ/R@i07rRaGUUnJhVapWzkbL/S2nZiZLS/kWL48zhSbeqY95/rx7Li12czGsaJQL8@ShBDLNJvT0bg7Wg9aRn1DV0LcdOTJ3marT2Pox91WLlDspCLjRTPYLWWUZb2d82zVfq@spaszJluPLSLtaHBOLNfFWLJlKpKWua3EI42FVM4mM@NOmlEFof/ElZgZ22pv6JgR1Ru5fkMzPGZ7pIZGk1Rw06gMqO7QMMJ5iRiue5FCcqZzJX5tFo1oWwmotQbNNMRqRw4ve9LToK5Ok3Oq1OlvqdFqm1vXTc5szdQwHw3PbtfGk74t6SUiNpiycqeaVstTLlIaSNsoFWaU9iAtVrhBMUAnO@N8Rcjll@NtR5gHpvmnRZ5jOaOeHIxu5chyrXnEYGxZJtrVXn8cfXqiR0J1EJeSs06zXjADbZZaDFrl8FN5YBg5rlOQUiFJWWRSg9vZPD3csG1jvV20IyNZ3NT1AJ0l1tVBpctN1bGRM4bcdNvPDZXKIhDp16Zi1ORnzFxiyl2Rjla1pifjqcu3o/Em0l0ISw4sQ61R0JhUcjqtETVmHl2mNnHDVG6NUnWULialZLIcCzS0QDQ/S9/m17zU7XSreZ5VQ8NROhipjcZ0gE9Vs@N6aD6O1qvRUDlNtEebRpPhMzGJmbByelrchLR4OZCKUN1VM9@YtidKVU4ne2sxFeTa6iraY0WlI2wjUapCe6aTeFFJ0qF6hOiYGbNTzq2CHqVUqATqmw3XH7GLICs@DQwPN9hOtrWuwKrypPzUZNrdRTktTafdSIpr07VUi15sjRWrletEPFNXmEx5vcytJq0ebWiZvBYbrat8ul4XRhof1MRRLbkW6WWvN2w0OjVl3m/M883oqLbl2Wm4a4rNSG1tEk9g8nSX5U5utM6IhjhtLp@U2/Wi36VCndt5ucMvPdP4cLAMSv0aXa6muiK7KDTGUbNTXWuVoizK1DxQG1PEqlPfbk0hqWarq8pgLXa326SUMp6YdYliy7eFTN/0xLO5ZKbWbrG6XKvdljNJdr6qrMr9qEfYtip8WJo9DYm6osgBfdiSoyk6aAQ64cw2zU1v6cVtat4utuOMxnTy3UqlxExkbs5FB7VMpFfheslksbQpimy3XtfqpU6bqHmU/nDYpmptuRwXy4VmWw0Xlnql14uyKzXZYOlCaD5aldepVWWx6M3jRc/AFNiguhUEprmSy5SQB9mJEcJiWU9X68Ym8LSdPo2XGbXfjSe120gyvRH5pbDc0snM0kMZufWKj0haLNAerG/FAVcZj0vN1CSoLbV2JB0minGxonRH6UklvhFK@XI3tzCFFj8KSR6D1qbtRrJjdLiNdMtFJsuOMZCh84lauJ1Kxw15mImVdMlDx7gUwfUqbJ0qT8L9apFXV@l1pbvJwJQjxoh1OqxulO4iNlPyJSNV6j2VYrFxZ5SfQcGLyXDCSR1Pih8JDVGuEsN@qTvL1hddatroV6L1Tt4T2wb12ydOndyy8U17W6NpQYyPl4XFOqiVudhtrFTj5OK62uyIwjjSCjTkW2VLZJTohE6KzGq5UijPJpyKZcdiqlNV9EyHy0cFtc5S1Lo3NGu9fqwUuKUbdGu@ogNGZUXR4kCRNoPqYBDgidTSKGm9FrPMevJmctCaNrlbmar2moWtuilnA0YnWU2LpcVqo5U3kh4ccuXbtFznJAbMknBk3NY7s21qOSJ64rqcTsWiw0AeJMgw5PhqEGIFztDG6ylVrizy8nq6mHV1z3xNNT3DwTocn3QnBsWVy@1qYZXVw2rRmCpEJMIF8j1dixrNp/mmkDYzk25HDqXj3fGolh9QlbZYijfSrWFUCNepwpMQ77UiNFcO9ziKaarzpQkjEjeeEeUNzeucLOhsdFF7CmcXCw@/WS5MjzaM3pZivfEszSw51hNMjtQndt0tyrRUjQpjo9ZbLfu5HliISnfZUYjcsKMFS1JebOW7tcqMqSebW5NKxXtcPzQe6IyoiMtm0AwXC8I4yomZ7HA2zeQLTwV6ID7RK0bWG41gLs8QUdGTMlVeproNraFsA6yQHNRilRW/Tc8nVVHIFwIZfdCM8K0SK2dhGJWeyrTWzd2Wh/xInlCiqtRaTZomhpFAttdvPjFLvlHfttV1Xh8Xk3U52BcLilrvd5lMQ6eq0VSukZ42h@lNLFLX5ZHQHsfaytxzG1Q5NqmUI0RUWAqpbo/qCFKQia63I3YmUMywN5vF8tQ2YmyppGKsprHxNj66nTO9YVW9bW9m1O18Payn@sxC8DBMndOIhrmth29ve57S5rZTGMudgshR7HwzNfKphVBcjRqRpCem0W1Plu9O1uX6WOtlqehoFGNawWAvZD7x9Y3RqBLdTDkfjGY25lrMzhbVdSyvJSOtzbrTCIVmw@m6FmtFmuE1s1Rn2ZSWG4cptW9ElXU7P86lhKxYEY3KdsTNich2US3kYllPWGAH9cGQFrPUU4uXzclYbJf6wVaE4sL5Wn01HGaS1DwqTrMF@RbGxBVbWW9a08Fs1KgZQYlQawNPIbKNbFvDRpVX6r1iZTJajaPRup7vTuOL7UBrSk2Ptu0URuptpj6XM9s@CFykGQ9PO3K205P6mSZdI8xIL7kCG5xJlaXNmCqE6ZKo0MX1/Dben/cis8Gsm142B@vZNNKKhtWFsI2avafwQuhEB8V5i@JGg9XEE7gl1NZ20882Qnq5utLKZl0VSnQsUB7OOvPsouOZp0u5kZnu0doo0CuvFp50GKyCWKUbD1RHpWmqMLttGPlGIE60c9JmEZveRm49dRhMFlOjFuvKAXlJ9Si5u1oKsznNVjNsV1@POrkyX@UDMUrzSNGVWYo8FQf1IWtqIYUijE2EX7GefBYsiIw0CLc8XVOj5zAXofvLYEkZBwOG0m@1ODOtRmedYFwI5fSuonbX6rQbkBq30dmKk0pTIiVs@ZDcafb46nq74uOzEM@2lp1krq/0gmlFm6wNnYnES4Eu@1Sf68GaqdXLHS6lNOYsK648azmVqeitJcGPq0m@l3taiMtuqJYMJTd9ng4thsspo2z72UFgWh8lJ@Kq2Qttm6tgir9llOZc0uZ6gKLbXSU7i607eaFEFLdZYTOJNVL1bqhTmsZnQXk8a9XpzawmidxwaCyYwmBcbjB8IdxNNeKzvGgkhWgnLhan1Lo6qg0jaV4I0YRnUphTgXSZCxazfY9Z5OTwk7RlquY2LiqbakcatcbLpFbmp51FNZWnUkxgebuuzYP5JhVcsKl5LFPSB7pMCNlwct2pVSLGZJg0uyG1HljGtGFdGvcDfH3CcnM6EgMdXOFHw00n2UytyoNqvmUklfFW8OirknJbyOVSCpEXe9Un44lVxUUy1KmVB42nRlIft8Mj0ygw6yeB2myUWjHNcZtBsmDMqt1iSylE6TmfqkQbE76sdNS6FCwRXDw660cppcUVF7QQqidDuafuLfdUWEaa6kwxuXZ2yJjVJii7QrhT0war@TY9ocV1MJTtG7Uxrw2ht063RGCRbw74pjhV1qtm0eyWgvMWM@uu5FlEYTVPKBuv1VhmHESTsHBfVeaqXBqb/VZ1WdIparKNLATtVihJRDmgjZOFZqQYYG9vB5l4h5k/lYVArBJaJFeBWrPiUcKClimM5zKdnjWnQkOCKUMvUp8W6VZV6oyHi3Q/vmkR28FIjCvF3kotpWerzGw5bXfWQZhetbtlw2g1@yZfWAZGxag8qk34diaXbnBpljWiNSWdrc20RXc0X@VDYWKaC/anlWhRGkdm0YKwGZQWWrxe3BbSk3zIM1CKMXPAmvJTTZ4@VUemOXqKSt1Wo0j1UlFOoZ82UbM/6VEGkY/Ns7chIbotTJhoR5kvFwu@1lTUwqbeqACbo4Fg@3ZEJbVeo252@bzA9fMdsPSLqlBo9Yta67af5xe8QshBEN80pZduy0aun5kNmVWhuRlJjGdWK61q4WhYjI88y/C8OllkwuFedF6sLnMZTY@sK6D1x/VNvSw0qxWCmVcG2ZmnKDJMTK9su8tQMyn0I6PKSlyFwpnkWpnEYh163Sjeco3YSCus5p0iM25Qq2F8ZszZDttMcqpYI1JPWnCTWZtZOpwtRfL9hjCNrPjsIlBIrlq9QsSMV8VeL/S0aq5mQjXHiO31chWo52oNUwmF193GcFaCVggT3HjdyEaFSkjgaWk7TOs5daR02CRNFanAqtNteNSx8lQVPLN6IBfUIll6XWdhZjxMLYp8ZNSZyr3bVD4@IfgQl/W0jUhhGHnqP1UkvT/1ROegcmJic9mogEkyMjvt0LohxgfMtpuO9dhRbstkS1QylM8v4oVAoFiOlweE0QrPQVqeVoF@MSMHGvVuO7TwZKqZNT9pDTvN9KoSGw6Yeb3XWhbRZCxI0SuxNm12NtXcuiMJkeysmRVThKfQWBm1uCY2M92sTtV5MReazvK3uVthUeIW66zioceFzmb5tJgLsWJFZgVdyTXNSZILDmKz4JoraMmnUpfY5NlskUnHujF9JnHFabVjTI1lTxOlZOgpvPaYzWldKoUzzXZfmXYm1arOpSuBqCFkZq15ZNiZrkdLIcsXCdGMLzl5fVuNmEpqk5P6nUqjyLfoDVePFas5fU2PqNxTi16aVCfWqrfHo6oulacwcHoGHVWNyaBSzInaIFhtUqBX3WSJj42N9C0dKxfXtY5U9dCNbHOaCRhL3UNN5rVAZqtmi0FxFR03G6U5raeX/MRTqkep4TSlrqpE2OSDPdaYxZsiMxh0KS3b3BpGJdYZeUoNmRKagWE0ld8y7VFQ4xeTQWwwv10@DQaVp1G3lYfm7HuESKvyRIwbpbwRFeMcw3dS6XJSXWp0UZ83xdC8rA46gYHoGawzhdVToETnpoURU61OttsUV9R7SiwzH1XS7GbaiXWJYLZG88OgoBU7madBbrKYcunymgv21bzh6Yeq68WtHotGmFB8yRrB7nze9cSSsuSJBiebSSCVXUYyFK83e0S25kn3VBV6QXMYYauUEeKrsml0ou1WNt5M59L5cinbF8vxVoHt9z2DRiGdTbYjxdJkFioNGCNFpSqTaStATMvpGU@ZZmwhtaSckb3VM@vJcNaYL0ar6LJsDLZKiV1I4zkjstqsV1aikWSj@xSu0cFshcoOt7ISiIbXcYLnRL5Iyc1ZvxeTsnlqIE9gAp0B@Z/1KwudE3VjEu9BzStbJZru1MZdPS9P6kChPFponDiPS7OJEBwSTaoVy0V7cknkaoPmPDoYSf12MRgVF2uYvw4y25KYoaDVO4PWZEH3I1kwXUOhp0JvMm8sq12jGc502@V6iOg@NTMiU8iWy92hyTPVGj3OLc1ONJbPMtw8NatmN6lRqrDKcZ1e3jP1BNo8t8x1k3K2y7PGejOk47SeFKdEZBqppMQMY67CXVEPpYuTWpCVC@q6Voxp82a9GEgVsw1Rnel0qpHcfSLdTXwuhTdjMZm87RYG6TGRbKQz00BXNLim4lkVMFgqJ7N//NVHhQi6rmAwYqlKvPXb4PYxF1dfOXgCnzyBXm8/OXcCOfscHyQg2u9XAy1QjtfRQW8IX9o/Q472JP3oPF60tXj1cm/Rx@yOE8A3dI4HeYHP4BVPNkIdOsq8J@OjpHyNALzjiXdQ0D4Yfj35B@MSvkCDd4cS2ITfqHNh3ri/SRvmCDrng6Hh83B1tOXpYo6pQQRCk7GKCPz0On5Apyr8CBnxFnC2lnO/ta1PX53kB@IMTcEnjTh8fgfOap@KgTCdorBaE8Xvz2Yg8IEsu421r/zCAEsxMToSx@d7kIrX9M7v4g/eCy7hIAVTYpW5sdBX/GysTpYiKZPadLTmNtsnkgyHSHRKU@BH0oPKZCIJCp9TF4VrjIzT9pFN@PMJH7qJzq3CJ4ihg0ydJOnbH/v0kXTjgBddLh1Xr6SUvJjvpNA65GN@F3lIKAn6an6nPFwpHo/b9CRMD@NxoYgfGfeVtrA9Ee9M9Eb/8/8L)

Languages that should be tested separately:

- V (2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) - I prefer to test it locally because it takes 50% of execution time of the test driver, see also comments for [answer 112](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138479).
- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

### Explanation

This is another addition from [A Brief History of 2D Programming Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829).

Axo code is this (see the first line):

```
"r"{\
```

Push ASCII code of 'r' (114) to stack and then print it as number with `{`. `\` terminates the program.

I had to realign some 2D langs to make them work again: Minimal-2D, the Funges, DOBELA, Pyramid Scheme.

Answer (score 8):

## 124. C(clang), 4624 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _       x _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00@O6O4/m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #0C8302",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #58007B",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002425 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4736 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaUnhpT7c0qY6FhRpJegQHaY1XR3o3IQ2h5xJCwbPaYJBq1NTm5q0Ku7PFaELE3UkBTDjRFIGAGUKuqYLJkmO0i1F5ia9PvcqIbZbmqZDskHnBfmXyS8mzauTCaf0DQCM0/lqtlDOvMqfoK9V3RAQCy8YhopxSXpREPhXgCn6mtMltZypnO@kWIyp6Wp/yiPd5lCAdKyqKMmCQfFA1Rmt2ewNYoA@oHWB61tglKjqNGahJ2OZlmhe0@iezA2DPC1LAFsMJWkBWUOvIP2ANtSJsE2AQSuC0KcNTeAlUeJJqbSwMAXFkFTFCNISP6bnkizTfUGGDBtSeD8go6fGVpRVcJDqqxQNH157Rfj67lAAGEVwKi9owBusvIqMBE44PJjrnKYBkcDABhBuShMQBcl0G7TAGRKKGmQxBKVP@KathVClOWW7lvRM4mgO6J3qBLch6CZUL0jw0kNBFwAlt5YFz1yXTGABsjVD1wROp5u6IHh3RXKnSChMxRJMrEiQNNvpqbtQLbqh@awcQU4zqQM90ry5pDg6mKYPn07gm3a5TqhCJU9/OXzAsCWE0MSa7uG8dPo3tME8PAjwXbA9ZqC/UICVAq7INKNqJsMFNCAwYAKBDIdBDAVm4aAmbxVMn75qiy2hsqD60Bp0SaHbflIzfqrr2Ms2TOXGUGlZVQbAT6isPlWQHwodD0ET8Cr0Ez8tzIBrqmK1kTonHG4OJWg0A5uE6wGDOB55b2kKwlDQFSB7Nkedcg1VnhI4yGmYKIDAFciKGEsi3aZFTpIxC6QjKotqXTCmsol5pkofWx6UgdAP0g4ZvNpHoIk6g@I4QEoioA9NtnoeIQqAoSFUUlVM@t2//nf9wQDwZHhe1fu2uLbpvsoTncYRYkFb0CiwqsLJhCyA82PpVnYoYMbJUp8zsXhlaRdBiCClztWp3KdVKFCfS9C1htwMuqMoCrwpWEJuKUI/PeHGlr6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodoD/noJV4gTogMhOYTE0xSQe0Au02mJ88n449nz4@CECcN@g9OmSYwQkIXPCIRMGd@2uS085sGhTKMkzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkKUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhKPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA8wQNEhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK7/dp1Df0KIwp2VOGUy5AVpCCmTheF7QTFtfQU0MEzTS62GHRAbsMTRoDKnDz6/LJmOJPbpulYG63mo9e0TkUMnY5lBABp1Kc7YtR/clHbSTvHxdOgDMXhXu@hlBdgj42fUOCY4hAEImLAR@aoJyA0GeDyV@CLKL1CmWerTGotfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aCSGPfsxTAWZdRSS8S6KALboWzwwxiKqs50I0vjbEV/HzBmTPYjVNYkwHmzFBhkuCLJnMw2spwZabjDYOKYS6Vlrc27NT2AwdHXopiAsQ9PUjGPQ7ZI5nPaC0KxMU1@WzKqCLcuY@lIyVSvck9Ue6FIDOhPjlMDw0560eFUjErdm@MigZmA0iQadhtH2eQoi4nGLBmg5Ep9D4K0kF9G2BIX16wJAAhQETnlEg@jPImiAxlLhPa4gkfsg9BCXn3ZhL3N5IYC51nzJqRNUGXSHDOZonWV1UDMiqBZbURM9ze0dntYKm9hibndwpEqK54v748eP7mP3Gajjjx8/QegUQ58w5IPQJxIKkBDCBTFEcvhJCFPvSQ6Me3S/3DuYF95HbLYFDiUrSfNw98fHkUc/d8/a1zBevaCXQA0BdAAvgMftTacx6PW6zuZQ0WBPtGpftzjbJ9JQF5QBJSw0VTfpSjVfeKplmhdpFzM1dEaWeowCg@HTBLobTDhce/LDzMHJDsG6qppp0mAYT6CLAGTPmShTnUIHhcmCNJHMEpmiyAqK9qbRnNQclGshKG1PSERdnazVi0EJ/FClXYcRFxrSO5M8HHPt1CimTu053lZ8AuMnOEUL8tSA5@mAat2uI23AJALivC0IMyhq4PMhJJnHrSNtyBRBiZO5oN6zyN8zNbSB4wjcV3uCvIhHA4IsBs3FKog9MR6lrAsd6L8HsScvtVjty0CZ0K0CC/FVAudMMJugy8tgutNlySCz6G2OU2vZe6BcVt@I7Gpp1yYlvDGp9tuBrm0sRE6grcYqaqJN6AmMntgOCpi@vs0pSsaQ/OyAvqHobQrJbUx6IvnZA3Bs2xZgqOBEF1lyidMkNG9UFSbFcwI2URXVIgVYJSkcUyeXIAxJ@@jZ1fw7xPQEcQpTJ6YnKRj@BlgglSSQYq8nvQcKfEHSneseMH3a28c2EK7hG@OA3mG8OdVNWejb1//2x31ogLfNM@SWYPLz43XgCfiGTRUQ320tOyvekJ/9LUtgRlNZ4ggbSOhbKHkOp2WcvA7sR43ajg4EhpwOjbt0GheEE39g5PqKnFmU64I87QvOdX8hhMW7JoiVW5EmpEZwRXuKDFHvZH9lQFn5cVqryyrXJ1is5QZJ2LS21S7CghtA5ZgtjQTK6jvodOwcerO@ADaCObV@cUnhW@0qafj9Wn@1IUMxrscKMBnjetI7XEQi4u/JtdVdcEwPiDI3toJPGNxfVasyujQYgC1jX98DAysTJgIaxwvMnFzeVTHK1NCspsDQV/DpsvX7HoizrLkOvAcI1ZTJz68ROyIIPPQNJBWX9AJbLJJeMVXmeku0e4a/Xn6wQDJ4gnpJ8z5fKILj6HoOuFk81LT38@MwTfKnUvtzW@uMBAGviqIgfKvPwrgjTTg5EO5vBd9VwY6duAntAR1xMw4sSJkzQEBMm83CDJqF/HxNaHEo4acyp29CXxHZDTnOVP@92eImjybxqizZkuncvKcLX5vuGzS4gkx@Nlnx7i1/@2At4zAdWIf2d2iVN3HG9o4cfYd6siZLOB3dEoyg@h7veHWO33d771CdCdbv/iFrtZeq71A/AZlIBszA3mbv898SV1z6Iz/7uTjeS5XJy3vjj@lrVdVhtmzQ4WAIDRyFrFfDgC3L1oSwWaq@L9OGJKsG3SC/X@MFWOWGYf3ul@ZttkmcEuCHVh9bh/dn20sUGd7oDPl9p3E5eaDK8eSA4eDnXQmY6iJqefv6vRpuraFY9psaam3uqAprX99V7WP4/5ZwkJVIHef8W8GvWFH71Jk9V3y/gjAjwFW3/ZUrhpIkZ5CxplLvNYDOD@fc0rn@I0aP97jrjB7akhjLYM1hhlQSAqZuGdD/mNKiXy@t/3066g3axLcqsdW4Y1kAjU1@3zQpHQ6xvzIHGwp9v8YS5akwFfZqkGpvJIDYfE13fD9RIbsah/ZiAgPMw83JNdTKngp@F9U4nuPdVxUOJ0vQyb9pzexVNRpY2BpOnWsQqGHgbcaBMtV2GneLd/WpUv8654aa07PV/g6RmPJrNVLy2zbTjhluCOS7X4Ec47Y6THjVCdgQyne0v42UrNNYvzuIScwG80jCJSD9q3iP6fXiINivYI9Aq0pjI4DrSN@neMLvzdQJcCoFczFFMJf4@x639ynSnqrKv6Z1QJ/2JTTTwPjEXfpvtdIx3VhOemC58ZuVy@9oAWeaCNzCKfG7DVsDlOZ34oy8XXj7yii1tQy3t@RzVT47PftGo9ex77LBZDDxVUBnuYtxAu90QYIsFYx8j/mjOTYtWaTEhU1rKXPjTXDwSr1oS2CM1A8Y/FCYCOT2KwY91x9NDefyLtBCxe@e5CBDliX3tqkkmN/ga8NUFcH4KhCpl7PAubec0oQbCMVvys5mCQE38Hhd2gnuX0w4toSdh2zfUAzWxE5VxsLScK77zd8lD004nXwV275uy@NK5bf6qbVcTnwh1ttlht924oA4Sbe37I21X8xBSeF1gWyeOfsz9AFu6U0nMBc0VT1IEziPh/P5vF7KyoTTiYECYA4U8UzA7UrL6cGgYZJnElhJpO/v6cMvi@PQMftCp2nXsYt@fLSwko2zwkIjLgV1K@v9IfeYPnQHAu5D94NyTIfcBFSQwbrbC8rtwIkSuVh0bqpOK9yE7JBi2KnpibUNC5Mu9HQYckpfFugWqCsyFVV1azPR2rFu4urjf/37vu0AMhCgkhPJgNF8oKDTkjoRhur8k1WuXXpG0zh0IEEc8yEur2HpgVyGNuaSCR2U@H3AnLBVbCbtbWTbnQpuaiizW1RYjYqaEp0bTKvRLGr6qmDJk13wOpdTKZh1TycKPZf65tAIwgxK4QWyTb3e24AQgimmrqI8@ukS3Rdw9aePhBH1IKvqmGzCICX/9e@tzXNIlFCEMOwUT3xntkqkUeWRHWueV6dAtYNkJeiqDeJBJnO8OcWBFXqDYMV7aX7IkV19kMSAs6eNxVj72rlMgw4UaDf6fuHm24kkeg4z9fP2fegx/Rt6wgj/7Y8Z7xebb64fAgnWcPlpB@TkBeVqOzkEyZtUN@06XLjsaqGXEXGqWQuV7QnowTBpLmePekIclIjcCXOyR00cERQcc9HzRzGgf8Ctl6C2Ok360DO11HygYdIxdJADFcpByHJpIr4euN@KWQ4X9C/0EGUlwNNsLAR3FkNk3OKfpLPO2n1ke3uFyQu9KVlsnIWD4UiaVOfwKQ1DIIZ0oa@ix839Tw/zR8ZwuPLwsPghFF4A21QdwH9ksOcUKvkvh8Gz0C@/GDCfcrle3CfWPhN078MvtVKt0Ghmmq0GsPHFquVBUdUn3EZFoBBoMsx0h6pMfJiAH7okGN9WGx@I3qA@2IAeD33I0acww6BBQ31YKxabra6A69AKWmlEk@xk2@T7sJvxVc4PJOsm9XWyKNlE2UoI723ZqRGZscXDbWwrS78jRtgE0LOnoJ0dFoD4fdmj9AhTXHQa2BIAthDwdbXXd/vYs5tK4K1m@0QioO3sGm2D7efYLqoPr3HtR2WxcAP2DpTNQOeDjLQIsZli5bE4sJdDL/9MbNFgqPvnYgvB9W22INh@KIcNb9kCmalvVW2LkmKmVG7VC3sq9o06ffiwB8sbJB@2q2ND7QEC8q0Pta6PM4RvPHILCzDTYIgRifKwfPuszqTafmSOzoUhdWh5m3DyZtQw6JlkSD1ZIN1LxDFPBrWJ@obsphioN2lU0UE6IxswRvX7oHR7SxN1NgxWQbJ/bm2iBxTadQCMCa5NCD/tohDWSL/1JwKdPIfJFv@zlfmQwBHMBrXH//FBYH73r/@d5fP4YEL4T@2wCOF/ZYV/YpBBb/22LBrXrEG2tEs12gBDwKr4hFts1QnHYhzrJWUKrT0BDs4IQxDcInZT3w0ez30b@AmNAMzEQQXHEVKeoD960JHnmGHQdBqoshgke7DCAtoBhiHi1/M8RR9UGPqYeCweZRkgMjBzEAYkC2FAsxB6vccgV9RM0tI/93j69PSUdhkw6RbS8ROLkcwh91PE9fOa0EOApSwr656GPJBlkwPSzuxsnkPOx3oxK2oPN@umH0/AgLLaBcZgDwkAiBejFZsfLhjkVZtV0OiKsDDJeLV0rEcw3RTizyFYnsgOogAgsnCjq@Rr2d1s7qHLw5Y0B7ebwdVBsAaCHbv2ic79T/SD@aA82h6zNAjMf9gjSAqE/2yPG@1aejJvHTg9r90vsTb054ai4nZvEailPWEmHGHYuHerp7hsVEAv9otfACX0BOhZvCCNVM3I5Aqly2qt8cYBkUC6X4O5affZqe8hEPTfP64D7ldS7zA1W2Qa19miw8ptqjbrJgixWTx5Tea@0l5T@k7pHWtn9W3ZJOFNQWzoexGTyWigSNYX32LfpDJbgDlr5@dNqR7vl5f7x9OzB@XgTfG/7PPNPggeoXBB6MEgntlueo/OKTn7xU18HsYIOq5HYdfmyYO175N1v4l@3y1x/XTNxjnR2ZlG18TwGdMXZowylWUq@M6eNdQ9yFhFEb88izCHXtA1DqkskropkKfe7PttU0PbdXn7IJDtzrVmUtWaeBMfaU6BOZcu8Ra0QRS0NT0nDr0wQSuZmzkdzBNxdYNMXZdkmgaqYr2P1pfIfiunO35m65SGMJECTYceVBwbV0NQZOhCN4S6yVLvhEvfL@i159XXvBCDhiZLpgfd/xZBnP5CbTxerAB7KgvoPXiaerRdFWnHo9BHnBJrU@BXTdXozZJDXnBCdZh10vkpIAcxEOjL6QTgRHKpCzhKCHRFDUBm4KPbIeIeSvHYdQhO@jEoPTgUFn1pACONx@sHlfQDy27cGTmvz/2guEEPW6w6xw3Cbcb8KhfMLY5x91xQUvrCwoO@8cePyB2Id887M7fX9UYGiB@o7RTaf@0Q6igLzrR77caZ8pVCSKXWimC376RSwaFBoWccTJygxIaplyEIY6hHnHAa7ZkSj1qDDtLk1vPgUfyGqXvpwBmOZ3NaoX0@MuWCC0kI0iSnSEKSjAtiHnxoxMOkoZ0x1lD6eFlJGn3PBoOPECaFeOlDXC3JgbmB6wxeCoxLyHJM0MIADH/HSNEcJpdIkXU9JMVSuNShA9TeZNKRB0PSAYEXpNb02Y/0RhtseqDF1VTq2G6NXXWYokEsTvdoDEC7R805Fifw13ZvAq6hEgOoHEyiJVAon68ERYH@6gGZmUDvpLkpCJnu9TuPIfo3D8OQEg4sEi9sfykgdPchmYL7i6yCPXPInJAZ@8kLjPs/P@DAL9pD/5L5IybInHzxHMrpJQPGmPfMczhMs77Ikc93qBx5DhU0R378ESf6L4dg7TwFXUHXAoACh7L3BOQZrKP0oXJyyJ16Dvvp8BHJAbc@n/cLZPiNwQS/HHIvzOGPYE34IUa3eqfn0PBidwgFg@wL0Ic95JDxg8x88bho1wKfdcDiDyWfD2kIHj4hAb9hHho@Mq48NBiytHBiG7nMYOKokV1bZd0Sb56MtBhoRx@vNXqM@L1aK@dPDvD2MzJ70vbZR3/4wwEbhynTp3jEo34KRz4eHdAHn13MkUt3fXnIz07c95wYDj4/1sa12q33weM@yFVdbNQFtfnphD5iqAPmKPRLgmF@/vlnsD7p@7PgWfDRex9wP957FmeJxNGJP5488n/2s27/yQEtsyGW9XrCYS9DPzTohwTHHfmi4c/KiSRJmtHvw1cd4hNbYImlUUo@wMfD1tzuWMTd@AmdwD99@gh/5B8@61v8/Uhi7GgC8vbz0Ut7nhfUwdmHxfd@nuBbzZJgm2HZ8APO2CLxj58/QJUFH/kcH38m8xjalUi6VPUzAtPDA5aN0eoBjHwLge7Ri0UAP9QBv1gcrCCRPVjCH4uf/MHTwYKmDn6TTvu@87NYh4LBJydEHfx8@nP6n/ChDmCecXB29vjy4gvcB39C5I@@gO/0/vQ0eHa2OAs8nt1TB1@og8ULdRB2gbg8HFEH6cVpnVBwnz@zaXm2J8FlCJ8GHu9rZTB@m/7waeAgXMzk/OFGK3vAwl1sc4uJEbytFzL5aguga@VCplE4L7ULrRrEG49PZ58/@4LAx8/Bs0egZPGD78yXNk2Tvns6CtJf/TzZ18U65CRQB/mzRYsJnAKxZTumTooJPMDdgxcK@4U6uD@493wKfwqH5NAsxI7Z8bVa3fxXqxAvLUIjVQ8NQ0O2Dw27CAmt0DK0XIQmapXtQ1CAv9DnarwaZSYQIYXERWgQUkIKy@5ge/9/UlWvqyogVCGbuQiZiDskwnVQrV4DMhGKH8GfFAohlYvQDP5DMpE09qenkDf08EDd066fBei5QdYdDLmDcbdbeozFtecvL@H48z0Z12Opx3thIZmPLtrvfnq4T6VS7seTA8Z4eGAsZeYKR10nCPLy8vSUzzQzT08MLnMsTg99n32Bz/BJn/lO7cung/4ZMjV4@vGBcnvmnU4Hv535bG6FSMCK66wTt29IAD6zd/LuBhb7xcDjuY89fnnxer0fHtwnbqsmHg8tgLXqcbEPi7BIh11eYsamYAxgI2hpxGPes7N4DO7jSW/AEyLJVpYHl6ZpD64gmRYHiY9DOp3RdW5JgKIwDD24OP3pwXUffkynUzESHQuk4rSqB1IRr8vr/Yk9PbXLCHsh2uVeuFTdTX952f7zfHk59ZCPF/@8Xoy0f8@8Hkj2xuBu8cWzOPWcejAOojDXl5czDBK4LxC693gfvS8vVhz8erynFs4zL/AO5/7/jP@qQRsa7T54OUDzQaGjMa@ntxS80bgn6UvZf@mPUAGPK@KOQL1cbs59f//5KHKUiN5/ejx6PPKcHgWPHs4ed5Sz131Agyw7spdmD5Bv1EHwpO5iwy43yuIJbk@oshCUYW4fSZ3sCoP7yXP0@pNkU74j3@f7o1TKKvvo6JePNO0FdFCYCz4HIL@0hz49O10L1Qal9wy@X2ibyRB@@QJyZqWBNeKx9yEeHhahEIGnT3rpwy8H3MsJwU@/uNwnO/JK8HvcJ2SHyvXFdcjp9@yj68V1@KX3gmbbEesl1kEsenJyFLXCieQJjNLskZ0SghSvtYYZgxTB4HjSc08OUJzcwHMv1CrdEwYSjHDaDpN8sViMCcPv4od4IbygTnAnx9o2cgVcVgeikymC74A2jBQFM4MetPycToRg/JNlTqdVUfxoxcMUh@4JAliZgizjQh3OAMAQlvtzmHV@pA5A0YD9awjwmdQ4YSoI8@l0Lqw/Ock45ka0ZwQzWPz8/rd/9S/g@/fw/XPr@uf/RyqGv7//7f/8v/3ub/4WIv8LfP9v@P7n3//23/6x9SX3/wDf/2cr7h/s7xac9aUA1//w@9/@xd/9/rf/6q/h@7/a379@/f3dX/4n6///tf8w@Le/@8t/wB/rBnD91Z/97t/@CZD4lxj@lxCGfzv6T@3gVqwV/FMnCPn@/SvgP/v9b//N39nhP9kG2YqHrH8K8X@zFf@nVIJu1eCnXjq/aG5dm4VM7oKK09lqJf/qErOBYnS5UGyubxNWqpM1tkbRLZTLr2/tC9VVpzTPoSgINEdbCpODERoPjgjSp9RZo9CE6GaVTibX9wu8j4TJfa2F96UKvSS3t3it1dqGy6VSKKYf6VjC7w8Gg/CDVz/5kGvw8CcHhH3fdDigrnEVNMVa2@0S5oCQLqRwgxGke66Q/d0ePrs81d6PhAtGYVCXBkOYe83VNYBhGDCurce5N6Neh7qA3jTBBwDxSXETzW@YloeoIPa9cDiVjCVTkXDSn0wlozE2Hov52bCfTSQTqZAfDO8kG0/GUqw/GU1FotFoyk@z4VgqAdM0pS@JDANGHOty0SQgKTw@fnOKzzGpweEZddAXRJj7fqAXnr73w0HfiaCnSdoVST6EaBfDwOx@yOlHi/vH9BdXOEInoASapV1@yrWiefoglEtGQmG87eFtNpnIxCN4@0RS4ZML4W0fbxOhZDGbwFsBb2PJUCiRxVsRb4vFXKhYxNuqdYsfvF06tyFA5eLhridz/BjCAwgPdFA6EF6Q@KkAQRWC6HGjmBzBzgvLt5@VldT7rqTqstqv9qrwsZIGAydlUF1/rKS9H5IkiipAWfMPFa9P1YX6ZCdVnSTrWq3yT0@ulxNsAZQFeunxfiH2m4c2pJUAsuoJ@adgtMQ@TZOueMJ1fARX1ydXBIILDx1ywzDkcj@4XN771OMnVyLmOoa5VsD9I/sJZjQp17ErkXDR3hNXGAQp5nLF6XDC5boDzS0MAm76k@tEF8yprtDhkxekYJUOnRBK6GcPXjk//va8X2yw3skLLuYAmc@elc/nh6/3E1IM1hcYlN7jJYx33pMXEEZHytdiSoP5GAzS8IWpFKZraauSHlfKQ5NxI/XgsodVa8LtcbsTYbfb6z4BJB9p11bf9p4QQmiLYR6n1i6oJ9Q6BVagXTVPKgA2Ch1IAVkWSf/dFk36@NgwOR2XYEiRx7QrnnJhNICcpqyyzmK9o2M/G/B/pqwBM85SBy9UHx8fiabok9QJzqvAkjs9s6m7opeJge9ii94T6tCNFLsjO7btAfk9pGmYowQialQ9ODw8hKlc88wVcVWDT6eMPSk7Y8hs7OHsxJeO5nxkhhN05nxnOIN984lGKV1AZ4Y@nqBj2crJGPJlQBsHgO7E94/5BKHcNCClTtCcch1olkG3xBk0/WDRevqbA2JM07Uvzo7qVCHLw8fX2GzccYM8pHf/SHt/U5HkL8lI4IwspqD00NBQL43UT4mfkj9dt6qtavFz6Dh5nHx4eDsxpA6MX7xqjP2NcnlycKy5I1F3BKZ96QOrvmzCe3AWTgQNbnnwaHtheaIJlDG4JzZVmD0QO7uf@c7NbEJmxlBS8o/6g4EU/qPrn385ZBi3m6bZw/hvAqfW/yn85KpWEa54zOVF7zTjp6efng5osIxoVziGEuxjaMv22bbUPIsjhfwJRwb5E4RNhAG3zh2mC94jhmHaYRg7Uql4Mn5A/YFhvrb5Aanr1UBREHRjOtm3HJjRpWsOl0qV9ZIgBK6nK0GHq3OOjTPI0DjK4Ho3DjPbcfbIsxVFjn/ajVsaDPqOYSxFYUgih4PRIuoEDxr@Jtk6p4/w8C30mfNSX6gPgGvKm8TtDH5OKOoDugjgrceB89M/GqYXt1RDXurDB1tzGWbQMJ8QOWayIwPsCfVCIXu4ft@gcaWW7JBajnYcbsKrmuWdLC9pK5NBVLM1YhIfOSx3i@AjWrSogNoc0aREQjlWzir@gwXWm4pISrFULkAeOk2LZMXfzu3Se3hyA6neR9FrF06HIAqxIDjhFAFHQEAHkR6C2ztBbz7eQyB9NIvpItk5ACiwH/yEEj8t2hnv8fYRsiN6kZdVAxBbpXusGtBHT3axdh2cAQErASzE2hGFTEYNfcD77dbD53XvH730F8eTyIOp9Ckd9q49SGxc0BjWCWkkIz/pW4JDjsSw2UywsY9@aNoTy0PDs4azYzaMeqGOTP/kxGoq7YS68vDeL7iyfPKbyY8/8j9p95PHE@8kbeLV55vA@DD2SBbIkZmepEE8tHvp8cS89/mkx/TEe@XBexh6YJh8oUSL2YbXrhvUXEkDLbj7ZHj9q3sl8Bvl0V@8V3xA8tR/dJde@bl0yL@Ar5Rm/bL/Oc3a9YAyzfTKp5xwp/DFRe4dBxsYK33cya7PDWQZe@T06p57TAM/ZMjo8xWhMkCncS/7fI9eKFyGxLcZT@Qff@R88tniRA4EvAj1U@RT8d6EwKMvjffHHu508Wl1P4X8xx64pqEY2QvEQz6b1y9r2oG@E@Cx1aYb0i0aF0jeAsibpNNHd5@O7o7SHz@u7heByaPfYv9xaCMNSPwCid9QDWJ4dOelX7GETMY9rh@k4x@CRwaYqxJYJEd3fm0rp0Xh0R2kaDDg2VS/oL4kBzc5GygoYbZHjHXUBjkJgMxpyPlSBjlTz@yj1yPkzRi8JNnglruqJsHkgEMfcj/MnpUARyAwzT5IDhMfFp8@UU7RtrsGlIzKpYeTKJhkkHOEdFwZIIcSWl7h39Kv@9Swo3PXFn@jdFegYXYRiW91V6KaSIczdP4eQVANfAm9nFgay3LSAWVDtAfAEO2BcAHUIsgkW0/YkGk7EVrLaSDIhXpCtFzX8SAJA/UTqLdNzwcVYpEBnXkPGZJ/lCa6CeRJghAtnZLyIABdhfoAlUAasA7SI30Gioz@8Ufavj1Nw3wmgWMBgiHcyMci0BtKofDvoBRwIJUjkFHUh6QQoO0DpqC72U5B0X9aQbbrqwcy@EZ@ywM2GL51@XGj0rA8vpFvXosMbIsPH0ZgItoEwT@xjyE/pL384cAe7o/pXPUaJuCF@nWmAb9gvSc3Z9Udr081e3M8kobHHvUkhThS8VydFbqXPNgvYO2BSKl9PLOwT1@2yjCzreT9@HgesP7AWiWAAfV4jUkwyKEnRlDVB8xcGkvM7mmleL4c8dkiB6MGnMPmkBwyOMsbP/SNG7qBE3wYzO1ninaOu5wIhmGf@hRwTr0kJ3sSj/wJOpZDL7RPiSLb4c6OHtk/xkUxP/FK0KWBRI4yHFoIdvKTA31MKzvpHxSe7tTnTA4lmkrBfPiYDvkxwDqBsBOIOIGoE4g5gbgTSDiBpBNI2QHWwcxamNlwMhKJb4KJTTC5CabWwWhoE9xgiIY3wcgmGN0EY5vgprTourR4kuClDxxukq4r6JjGRpNOGj6AopgkMgZo2NeRUSA0/AYSskffREJ5yd3IRCpkF1RiqggUDsc396B9HNi0x6LKb9Hht0q27uxIGKsoa3ZDBLag66CVCgs8ew6EzntMo98sRYHapXlZ4MAYEEywUtJFkH/Be2w9b6Ivj9eDlIAY0uz6HrILMCWFPCw5RtESnz3J4X3JFrbwXmzWkz70mjFbXsg2kRaVx7vuxQRjdCduG@tHVLDI0XcgwhYEtsGGSnmrzKY@3Vtk5OtF7iDcW@Qboiy8sX25kDcegjztZCXjP8GWdsqz7BSBtDaYAfaZuUQGXjUoPniU/sIeu37/27/@3@nf//Yv/pb@3d/87f/3n/8nDP8n/Pk/wWahw2uAP/8L/Pn3@PO/4M/f4M9fbmUi8JFj1@/@@j/A7f/4H@nf/Yu/sJL@zd@5/NE1IkjBqE3Ov/qX@PMn@PN/ufyxNeBf/ZkFiFlc/hdqx7TyANSf/xeahtIQyxrZX/89Tbt8YGB4bMm7t/r4o9f7CsGaDfck9Pg63frlhzqyPeT1uQCvfcdu7nzYAN4t5DqHh8Bu@h6YM5YTGWppnuOH6LBtR6kG2j88mjCqERyAvM37YPTYqwNuqP1/Tx/Tbh/CQDR53ipt6XC7/na9XZtUhPW5GKAOj2qzUWHYu6YEprcUyDeZCSyNIE5byIyUtWTE5m8FD5l2BhCXI1mS6WG9lF2WkxsmPbR9Vif8b6a6KLQ4DFnPK5Ezcynb95jdKnBH3bxqNijldQxMGTePLGxnJRHCRIMmgWxrfiNj8YZwwf8a3abl7G5TqBZfdRj89MDEHG9rpHVBadrl@gYsctqG96LFFdmFt@i1Ae5Dx5FHavvZiX3ArtvbWxe1FRdCGdL7HoJhq1KWylgnsbtJ4a2k8FYS0GzhJLomFg6/ooEMHKgXva8fF9lVUbvZNsKFPcdpByQD5oLWQqBflKfGMP0WNdHIu8ruLfItlOxj2u4nDwrROWe0y/smA@DczZN@3Zb7UYfewLxtqP05kds7MTut9T6mnTxbnYJwj3rNpXXLsal9Lbdb4FdQs4@@7ywoHPonFhT4zoLisW8X9LpZMe8O@vf5@22146iJtYbfILM6/sHOAIVD41@D6G3UEVKsk6DHC1OejD3l6c1V2rPnnFeIZ5zn83cOd9W3ntrHSUxFNQVreeCzpsKUQ0UreOsk933vU7APTh8oqi4Y208DSZZnteLGx@94daDAqObHcwIk@5hh3HK0HsbeHVfWI5ttheasw@ERtcUotDyfniRFMp@ewPiURe@GgXgb5NHd1U3hqfIQ2srvWZu2Vc2j4vkmpvfbOIm9a2VrSvzYU9XsRDcUkqFhQscLMky@6CHHj/H9CIQlWEXybA5apD3T40UmDtWJOhAUFR89xNyv0Jc2uJEgTtMILX6a89P8FkX2JNrD@zmvnfXqV2elr8IezrvOH95FsMMMP62/5jFyVt9T3NO7xVnZnPIav57exja9ja/TK0q6Yb6mmUTiag9ef13REc8GAwBuyIh8mwy//VzxG3J2SFlH4/nJVobvJrEvGDwMf0hpBkAzNnhQBPnwr@8MuFsT3n6P/19vQCd74XubjxizjSXom0kBbT8yRTPIcQwKL3gAvORF3fO2uLVo57@zLHuiQ2Z4ftpFFJeCXtPQMTVNUIz1BquD@Bsyj74Qb@SeOEikrcQ9NOkzPz0Ov99E@ae@IHNLoe@xIf1beJ0a1wWuT/TV91UcFR1Reqp1aLYn5Gd3TDHydAsBOn5HZDj/zOt9X6wsEGktPWQzjlBYep9/ZOHutWrGRdC0tQei6qBBD8gD@@SYBG2pLa0n4mTrxRq2HrXGH6slK/ig4DcZAnywXpvA@jfFer@mPuuedZW@Y0RYwwZ3q4wPvTgY8bGTt23461j07ZqSVYZ1prTTyjvWyXstLn2txbekwpFJyyr5PpH8ltB9t8xtiZqFbKPCcr9uCHmDOcfJMs97tjFaMV9tMVV5oxMwDltMVd4ZVZ72KNR1TqLpTDyfNW3ZF15KgmAJrjO4tuGKCGEO@mQJlFM3tGudJS@SMuG0LavFjrnn0Rbd4qJ3ex9xC4pywriQ@7Iuk3@3TP5NmfxOmesesFvkFhDF7xRptwI2z9eaQBZE8x3tjEk4c4fL19Q2fBSV03Hv9Ytbch9Lfto9cx@DQnYL7uOCB5Syu@8@zpOA4T5ukMDYfXwFgU3fcv/iPna6BQLocEsCnzHeVuF4z7uPcx7vC0Vep@SUG3Qfr9sUYD5Zt4QjL9byas/e9VfXq6qC4LeMSj@NEmPARcVq3T/6yTcE/wTUPgUHEj@m6fARAcYJyM6gsTViWOXAsBEk72vx7Bs@jp2lKXt9Y7OGAum@9NaiCkrJlOgj94F7VxlZhGEqWXyEKxCIevN4P0U0@2Zm9i1y7NJBQkkj75ZPuBck9kDfQ9LvAXh7EUfe5HfaaxeF1YDfRydmfo/ON@Q4xRGK0BnAu4csZOrP7q9UCtt6lxa79bdb6O0aATZiwAGxWomg3dLpYMOhbUoK01RtV0hIKu72Sdt58GN3SpTeV9mIVrB75jvJJNquGSqG7c7v/Vp1tvIhaTsqCBPvQ49WL1uPC0QXY9JG121ZqlbnAxK2dE6fPDIsoNjm7SCBs9SNn4wV7w1DTl6rSKK5dtUkZA7iYxxTzrRK3@zL4MMdv2766uQEExxoRARbOdelWPpV/RX2u2rZ745B7TDhVQH7DOv9Q@lb8/qro@wryuVNsW8bEBP9dN671zhal7BhOcwOtizzr8naGxMfD@y3jHyr0DX2V9a@w7b1nOAbfHs9t7BwoZWgz3Yjx7gwOw6/z6i3Fok8CzpGSxBLsvFYFV9Tuqna12m1Kr6viTEFx2i4/OoG1ncbeLvxEB@pgP6K5VYvx3cKkX2Kdd/GNfWtnQtr10FFL7H1WT9bkaDuif/a2kULIqpP9Xy1Uu7CoJtIJLxvtyKw10LezThOfXWbYD1tCfvxyATyWkL0nRiquvnxQXG9dSkjEWAMcGTfxhI/u497bV22pc9f9V3IZ8FucdTGNd50A25HK6Gpw@GQLdl8NYEhguk54mwkjnkL/PaT2RruGqF04IbO0xMZvp6e0Dnn6ckexbBp1ttIfziwX0oS3nq34MGuN9M7b2zFBYDpxHqznb0AZz9xbPmhHOBbJNfve13nmiqm5Dg74PoQblGtPSM8EdZrvXzSibHeEQmS6glHcQobjuFTcVYuhMaFT@JaaZfz0TJ08KBAQ1MV@yWSY@tFo@TYQsNZeiVkT5U5R9xArFLIw3xbFFkOWc6@GHkvHDnc03oJH6dYS8gOb/y0MAiSHZ9wCqYcY0mzTtRZu34YXpKJEEx8tIDHPVmY4LvZQHb3rCZfS9Aqw6I0GIAgMfZBqZaDSxNf1xZQxUBu8w7dNnnDnn3wmu0TRs43tNeBgZ2enUf9DTocB2sq5QfObr7AWHSTofFx/hBx0iJQ8E3AJWEFk/6tvB89S@/ulXU@XsT30fOELfuLNVJA68gg8soWn8nnl@2laXvTkuiBrZ1L59QKyj5lJE32KYPoo6Z5XAcu5ywPDFpuE5zMOw/Be/D4hWPqg0IUD3qA0bzlWwMGroJGG9le865dUhX6BzoSJq9vgvKIlUqKBRzWzt4OdkiDrEis5d1nKxjXD33XD7iZSH04QF1oyRrmd0QZw@QIso0s0x9tdNaGCnZlqws4N7GtmwhMNT7sKfijx@UDLD6X17WDCeDt3Y8PluZ9mxWUovcPTLMf7xTVTCbTnLB6/TwzyAwz9S7cZ0NlX2cULTBM4ULuZ/Kl3vJcTTRnYjjU7N5kexFfLdFfaNLFJHehFSgp2p347iKL1EV0FctFchk@dCuel8VoIncr3hpCRhZSzGw0vukLda3H6oZ0Vbmu1FdMsXXTHtyMxLtOZ5RQGpRWv8sObhbCTbKjzNqtVMm4Edq5ijmujMwpu6wmOvHWXDGy7WZ2eLkszceLUlztSrHcjZBoi9rFnF/GNP6iRd3NmsN442I5TrGT/jKTM/rdhM/HdHPZQfKC79@Jl43cVX@gx3qxcSPFRWaTS1FbDq8ulOfyKNeY8T5tVCzFZ5RSK83mQrQz7skXyl293e7ls7X5mDXutP4o2rmemr2kHo9EphlhOIrGSlNTT5azmauEmc@U2kX5tm3eLdvJGmVemM1E65JPyb5Z1eQj03yLMULtxaV01ZjHL8JN9UK5lEuj2vh8el6Ttek4H5WqzUlUH9wWe2o4fHHTmF10y5Qevex0k/VROJnnFzxzFVPVSaSZqpT168U0@1wVOjm@kRV68VA2dltgR9fVJV@dlev1Tk3rtCYJ44qV74qhEVW95RuZ7LhYniTZZmVZSp6XGtNcrrSY9cLiQM1M@53I9W18Xq4Ipc4NE7ngpua1T8pVZWZ0eWks262r0m3FuINufX0pRcXlItvO6uJzPmdc18tMRR8PG9GR0tfaCSmn8pe1UtQsjTMX885dqpQdC2KtN1bHzY7cmZpSfsQUqWVufNPqCfOitJpzhWi5fcOMCnXeTGQGkQYzEsXeWK4aq8F5eTVoTHuDfqp6HsoLz1f9bDtWL2jsddGIVpQl1W1mRWlVvxHZcS11UbrrFTLStRLL1QStdn4xW4TDXUmszWMrdnE7KkalBR8NlavZ22vfzWW47iv7stmaGqkOqHC@eN4ZxK58alFYMWWRe07kfPp0Gl3kp/iCv3JLkfVJTA4li03fMGHondT19bxnlG7ruQ4vr5J31@Nx/K5O3c5KhqqHk5fFTIqpjUP6OTeqlO4SklKMzrPnciFV6qxaSbNQnsrJi/Igf1nX880Jf5sqDBrL5XiQvBRq5XGGEpL5en3UG7R7i27DqC1D11F@1PMVzguV5wH043ajGL5sZeODaT3Svsors1qz6Fupt52ylquM2UItOY03E5EJNVtcJjMNU5G0/Pl1Kn4zlcqFTH7QyrGqINw@81fsmGs0l6GkkdBvirc3muEzmz012htmI8ub6y7TvjOM2IVE3S068VJmrPNX/YV5aSSaSlit3oTYG7HSkmOzjvTcramjzIS5at2umN58VVzUTN5sjNVYPxEbny@MZ311pV9Rye6Ik1uVnFoe8fGrrrRKMDFWaXZz4jXfvQyHMq3BxbVQvJgNVi1hEh5dPE8veI43aplu71yOzxaaT4wkZ2WqWencDhLPz6GeUOmmpMy4Va@VzHCTY6bdRjn2XO4aRpFvlaRsVFKm@Wz3fDzJ3S25prFYTZvxniwua3o4VKAWle51mx@pA6No3PGj1W3xTrmehuO31ZGYMPtjdiKx5bYYSlS0ui/vq8nnvcEy3p4KMx4sQ@2mpLHZzGhUparsJDHLLlOGqZwbV5Ve7jIjZTLlZPhGCycuxrnzi0VfarfalYs@p0bverlIvNobhML9bKUwqEUng0StkoiWc1Szt7yps/18UmKHnJwbXS6jWqoczsaZ9rx@cTNqDpWKnMt0FmI2wjfVeaLDiUpLWMUTzHXINxqmLpVMKFqLUy0zb7bKxXnEp1yVrsO15ZK/7XHTCCc@dw0f310NV9W2wKnysPxcZ5vtaTknjUbteJZvhqrZRmi6MuacVq5RqXxNYfPlxaw4HzY6IUPLX2jJ3qLSz9VqQk/rRzSxV80sxNCs07m7uWlVlcntzeSinuhVV31uFGubYj1eXZjUM5g87Vm5Vewt8qIhjuqzZ@V8Mb1tM9HW@aTc6s98o9RddxaRbquhciXbFrlp6WaQMFuVhXZ9KYsyMwlXBww1b9VWK1PIqIXK/Lq7ENurVUbKGs/s4orhyuel/K3pSxWKmXy12eB0uVo9L@cz3GR@PS/fJnzCqnHdj0nj5zuqpihyWL9ryIlsKGKEW7H8KsePzkPT8@ykedlMsRrbumhfX1@xQ5mf8IluNR/vXPOdTObyankpcu1aTatdtZpU1afc3t01mWpTLqfEcqneVGOlmX7d6SS4uZq54UKl6KQ3Ly@y8@vptDNJXfq6psBF1JUgsPW5XGaEC5CdJCVMZ7VcpWYsw8@r0fNglldv26mMdh7P5JZifybMVqFMfuZjjOJi3o9LWjLc7C7OxS5/PRhc1bPDiDbTmvFcjLpMiddKu5cbXqeWwtVFuV2cmkKj34tKPiOkjZo3mZbR4pfSOR8fzlpGV4bOJ2qxZjaXMuS7fPJKl3yhJJ@l@M41V2PKw9ht5bKvznOL6/YyD1OOJCvWQjF1qbSnybFycWVkrzrPV8nkoNW7GEPB0@HdkJdavmy/J9yIcoW6u71qjwu1aZsZ3dxeJ2qtC19yFdHPn3l1eM6lls1VNRQSxNRgVpouIlqZT54nr6q8fLmo1FuiMIg3wjfyubKi8kpiGMqI7Hw2VxjfMpZNFgZitlVR9HyLv0gIao1jmEXnzqx2bpNX4fPQTagxmYfCxvWcCYldRVp2K91uuE9lZ8aV1mmws4Lvwsx0G6M6fy4zlU69tFKX5ULYaGUqOfFqOl9q5aWkR@748nlOrvESC2ZJLD5o6q3xKjvrUR1xUc5lk4m78AVIkGHIqXk3ygm8oQ0WI6Z8Pb2QF6PpuK37Jgum7rvrLmKpYXtoMHy53KyU5gU9pl4aI4WKx/nwRUfXEkb9ebIs5cz8sN2So7lUe9CrXnSZ66Z4lbrJNe4SQqzGlJ6FVKcRD/HlWIdn2Lo6mZkwIvGDMVVehvo6Lws6l5hWn2OF6dTXX86mpk@7S5xfJTuDcY6d8Zwvkumpz9yifSmHpEpCGBjVznx2W@yAhai0Zy2FKt61tMiVdCE2LtrV6zFby9RXJpNNdfjb6KCrs6IizuoRM3ZZEgYJXswX7saj/EXpuRTqis@hOSvrNzeR4gVLJURf1lT7MtO@0W6UVZgTMt1q8nreX@Umw4ooXJTCeb1bj/cbV5xcgGFUei6HtHbxvHzX78lDRlSVaqMeClF38XChc1t/Zmf9m9qqqS4u9MFlpiZHbsWSotZu22z@RmcqiWzxJjeq3@WWyXhNl3tCc5BsKhPfeUTluYxSjlMJYSZk2x2mJUgRNrFY9bixwLB3nfE4ecGs4saKySjGfJQcrFK98wnbuauo583lmDmfLO5q2Vt2KvhYtsZr1I25qsXOzzu@q@V5qzSQWyWRZ7jJcmRcZKfC5bx3E8/4klqo6Sv028NFuTbQOgUm0esl2UYk0omaz/3a0ripUO18@SKSyC/NhVgYTyuL5IWWiTeWi9ZNNDq@Gy2qyUa8HluwM3VcyGrFQYxRb42EsmheDIpZoSBei8b1qsdPqPhqWikVkwVfTOC6te5dSCwwz42@bA4HYvPqNtKIM3zsolqb393lM8wkIY4KJfkcxsQ5d71YNkbdce@makQkSq12faX4Kr5q3N1U@kqtc3k97M0HiURNv2iPUtNVV6tLdZ@2apV66nm@NpHzq1sQuHg9FRu15EKrI93m66EqZcY7mTnY4Gy2LC0HTCkWuhKV0OVicp66nXTi4@64nZvVu4vxKN5IxNSpsEqYnefYVGglupeTBsP3uvOhL3xOqY3V8rZwE9XLlblWNmuqcBVKhst349akMG35JrmrYs/MdUJaL9wpz6e@XAysguR1OxWu9K5G2dL4/Ma4uAmnqGZRWk6To/P4ua8Gg8l0ZFSTbTksz5gOI7fnM2E8CXGVPNfWF71Wsdyv9MNJRvNJibl5FX@@7NbuOFOLKgxlLOP9Oee7KIAFkZe6sYavbWqhCcxFQrezyJUyiIQN5bbR4M2cmhi3IikhWtTbitpeqKN2WLo5T4znvHQ1orLCqh@VW/VOv7JYzfupcbTPNWatTPFW6URyijZcGDobT12F29xzbaJHqqZWK7f4rHIz4Thx7lvI2fy13phR/UEl0@8Un6firB2tZqKZ5W0/FJ3ezUassrotdMOjWi8zFOf1TnRVn0ey/XNWqU8kbaKHmVCzrRTGyUXrQriiLlcFYTlM3mRr7WjrapQaR@TBuFELLcdVSeTv7owpW@oOyjdsvxRrZ29S4wvRyAiJVkq8HDGLSq96F8/1hWiI8g1LEyacK/ORy8Ktz7zk5diztGIr5iolKstKS@o1BrOMVu6PWtNK9oLJsuHZ@aI6iVzUmciUy06S@Su9q8uUUIhlFq3qddwY3mXMdlSthWdJ7a4mDW7D/dqQ4yeheBJ08HW/d7dsZerZeblbuWgYGWWwEnz6/Eo5LxWLWYW6EDuVZ@OZU8VpJtqqlrs3zzcZfdCM9UyjxC6eBWa5VKqXOZ5fdjMlY1xpXzaUUiI06WevEzfDfllpqTUpckXxqcT4NsEoDf5yGhKitUy0@Nw@559Ls3hdHSsm3yzcsWalDsquFGtVte58ssoNQ@IiEi3cGtVBX7uD3jpaUeHpRb3br4sjZTGvX5rtq8ikwY7bc3kcVzjNFy2kqlWOHURwEha7VZWJKl8NzNtGZXalM8xwFZ8K2rlwJVHlsDbIlOrxyzB3ft7Np1rs5LkshJPX0WlmHq7Wr31KTNDypcFEDuXG9ZFwI8GUoROvjS5DjYrUGtxNc7epZYNadXtiSrnszNWr3HieH89GzdYiAtOrZrtsGI36rdkvzcK9y4Tcqw77zXwxd8PnOM5IVJVcoTrWpu3eZH4RjVGjYuR2dJ24lAbxcaIkLLtXUy1Vu1yVcsOLqK@rXCbNLmfKz1V59FzpmWbvOSG1GzeXTCeb4JXQ8zJh3g47jEFdJCeF86iQWJWGbKKlTGbTab9aV9TSsnZzDWxOhCPN8x6T0To3NbPdvxD424sWWPqXqlBq3F5qjfPbi/60r1ByBMQ3x@hX52WjeJsf37HzUn3Zk1jfuHo1r8YSMTHV881ik8pwmo/FOonJZWVWzGt6fHENWn9QW9bKQr1yTbGT625h7LsUWTapX6/as2g9I9zGe9dzcR6N5TMLZZhMtkKLm8tz/ibZ00rzSeuSHdww87vU2JhwLa6e4VWxSmWftcgyvzALoVjhKn5xeyOM4vN@YRouZeaNTilupipipxN9ntfnY6FSZMXmYjYP14rVG1OJxhbtm7vxFbRCjOIHi5tCQriOCv2QtLrL6UW1p7S4TIi5ZMLzVvvGpw6U54rgG9fCxYgWL4QWNQ5mxnfZ6WU/3muN5M559iI1pPpRvuBrGvHSXfz59vla0m9HvsQEVE5SrM9ursEk6ZmtZnRxI6a67KqdS3a4XnHFFq6YTPTiYpoqhcOX5VS5SxmN2ASk5Xkevr3My@GbWrsZnfrylfyiP2zcteq5@XXyrstOap3G7BInYxEmNBero3prWSkuWpIQL4zrBTFL@Uo3c6Oa0sR6vl3QmVpfLEZH44vz4rkwveKni4LiCw1KreXseToRkpfXMifoSrFuDjN8pJscRxZ8Scs8X7Wp5QVXuGRzyXZSH0v85ajSMkbGrKOJUib6HFv4zPqoJl3F8vXmrTJqDSsVnc9dhxOGkB83JvG71mjRmwmF/iUlmqkZLy/OK3FTyS6L0m3r@uay3wgt@VryslLUF6EeU3xuhGYm00o2as1Br6JL5REMnL5uS1WTMqgUc6jeUJw2LIXm7cxVPzkwcuehZPlyUW1JFV/oplAf5cPGTPcxw0k1nF@phcuIOE8M6jdXk5Cem/WHvqtagrkbZdV5hYqZ/UiHM8apush2u21GK9RXhnGdbPV8VzcyI9TDd4nsxYpt9iJafzrsJruT89lzt3v93Gs3LqA5b31CvHH9TA1uri6MhJji2X4rmytn1JkWutQndTE6KavdVrgr@rqLfGn@HL4KFUelHlupDFerLH@pd5RkftK7znHLUSvZpiKFaqh/FxG0y1b@uVscTkd8rrzgI7fqheG7jVYW03M9mYiz0dSMMyLtyaTtS2ZkyZeIDJfDcLYwi@eZvl7vUIWqL9dRVegF9bs4V2GMaL8im0Yr0WwUUvVcMXdRvirciuVUo8Td3vq6N6VcIdOMX14Nx9GrLmtkmez1cNQIU6NybtxnTDM5lRpS0Sic6/nF8G58M5n25olZ2eiulCtuKg0mrMhp405ZScQzN@3nWDUUKVwzhbuVrIQTsUWK6vNi/5KR6@PbTlIqXDBdeQgT6DzI//j2eqrzom4MUx2o@fVKSeRa1UFbv5CHNaBQ7k01XpykpPFQiNxRdaaRLCY68pXIV7v1SaLbk26bl5GEOF3A/LWbX12JeQZavdVtDKeh23gBTNdo9LnUGU5uZpW2UY/l281yLUq1n@t5kS0VyuX2ndlnK9XQoDgzW4nkRYHlJ9lxpbDM9rKleZFvdS58I1@42ednxXZGLrT7nLFY3oVSIT0jjqj4KH6dFfOsOY@1RT2auxxWI5xcUhfVy6Q2qdcuw9nLwo2ojvVQ9ibjfOLtZWoixZYDMZM5b5e6uQGVucnlR@G2aPB1xTcvEbBsUeb@8KuPChF0XSFg1EyV@jR5u6p9zMXJVw6eICdP4OPtO@dOoLPP9kECov18NdAC5fhdLXxC@NgqhOxtBvHQa9xaPHm9txhgneMEyAXP8aCPyEHX4s5GqEvHzGsyPkrK1wggO55kBwX3wcjjyT8Yx/AFGvwOSmATeaLOQ3jj/SZthCN4zgeLh3U9nmxteXrYbWqQQGgyThGBn37XD3iqwo@QkWwBF6pF775t/dDJTn4gztAUctKIKxB0kaz2qRiIaReF1ZoYvz6bgSIHsjgba195jQfHsMlQPEXO96AVv@mf3Kce/Ud82kULpsQpE2Oqz/vjgTqcibRMa6Pegl@unmk6FqUjUFb4R9qHZbLxNEPOaUzAb5JOhewjmcjnEzlwFs@lIufM4WnBbpoOrI91@kh7ScCPP8eukzdSSh9NHCm0DvmY3Mcf00o6dDK5Vx5PFJ/Pa/rSpo/1eTDiR9Z7ok1tT8R785E8tc8c0dfOo/V4yDX6/qoiXVMVfqi6DZq8@3D7mRNy@pbTgSactt2fZgJvqvp2jIjyxE12OuLbKNwl5l7llFQHzlxqAm7drU8lkPGlsPjzYRqPnrxNxxp@@IBHaJzYvhPbFfhCadOeLPHH1AfCT9wCx8fpj4/tQ2F4GuX2wwcSJ1mRFi20ZHgw@cRJ5VVtaWeWLJAnpy6nWyjPPLi36vV/D6QD1QOZfMJXkugAZoFY7N0BpwE12Rr1WlRhuCwo631QPMfHe4KnnNAfnTTnxB@ER7kh5@48mbRETumByyltg5IzMGivfeIEib2X8KE34kpw5raSPoymE43sPwctem2O4PvhnjRO0tc5g8a0h0/30iwyQ3KIxhbAwAuegTbjTGG7aZy2QMc38vAV1gfx1cih@UAwz@n6EnUjPnyA@PoqyfPBegGhhzZVy7HSIsPOS6rhtZsaGIenqLo19zFN/OBOIIpsiZ5spY4gFev6TvIEkiecOXwneYi4p8Z7yTok42sJ30mWINl6JnJ/ugrp1k7/OwAmenmCuD6Z6pPJSbLHOtADjwJ5sRS2h/b5HMauRYC2GsZqj938tH00Cv3Rah1L2HbEC/onESsLAEXaY3cevN9IC0nFQ2Y9llxslWnxhP5Cf7Mw2zkSWPxESgK1i@V7j3bw01sEQP8DVUq/TXcKt1p7XdEd@QnCsDPA1gZmRehffvkaZbYg7sof@@hIn9VC6Ie7VUOLWxs81mvLNu1qZVrZmfbnsY@O2dZujo/Eph5OpwxvVIjVtzb9WpSUPpQBiD9uR6PLk5f@tIm5Nx7p47X22PDR6hbf5mP4jfSgRxTpkX66twny389VDuUecnIwIvc2ygLPCeNO3rDTWEMHdqHPAHrNzVdyxu/IjN1Lf21lv682B0Af6dSENyeWouXBNDyzCdxDHme167ZOsJAduo@teHxnmrSLTHoHmXWe3hMgME@BBhzZHDXujImSErSeSQU9HwpH/cTF3AJ52bDJUVbfw6d/hs6FjLOH7Cm@RmZXJdF7WPMGfF1v5NfZ6y73qnqWpt9fuXvroWb3JzfSSL@VJyJ1n2CUPKZD9PrgphP65dt66B/HmS@b5tuxdwzP@7rCaXRHEr9HBF/eYfQ3hWy3CuFHeofjU/Iecu2bQxI5hHD/oLRxrX9yYhy3S6tvv2uBIVUnu@lIs4XQSQBDeTuX37a5zjaq0z598cl0jBv/xgrDt7dZUgEm@wm1rc5xOlckg/d27ProKMKR7RR8kh0tTN2hTBId2xbMYCdfkH/CZraYjPyEPj1Q1b7HMZhsg4FgcE7oACC/dZzV2qyyzMtN8VCcbfTSA/uUD2fcPYGYj3YUGVcgAo1PWzaRiKMB6TYn2G227BvJIC8XJOk4GkFRztMH6KxoaR/6@HU8Qq9NoA97MzkaH88kIydX2nqejMQ76sGV4xR0DMXmsKbWpy6MXzcEwpzBRHtzviVpg5c9qwzWGZ726ZZftqcu0okURJt43eiOF6T3ZE3N6akLi1kL/MsfDj4yU0NnepLCCMqMxtfNUwe0oFjv1DnGV0oHkugojG@EtrUJ8csmToggJtBSWFpQEeYe@63ReIqoy0tZZ9IRp0WWwoN7id@4LMz6YPVbJ7ZoqrEgv0uYLISCU81USYpdEDm7jv5F@mVznmqIPEVkzxhsck4Jng2MB58vsGKXlq9kgLUMJBZPJfZuobjHnEThuh5cLmw/JNT2J71/pIygwPFDJAJl7xdrOgXNRST5hTKcpsez1pAV@PAKBGXrlAmN@I5iEcQ6MZbkHqqP9ywGrBji4opyb89TKOIQjCmyqmoo5OgKivlPgQEW4z80mvlCvR60X6pgeayjl7vlx4yPCJID6@w3vttuvOitjscFWo3yASuLuK3y0hvkRP8SHmGxNpuwK8yRnRav8DxCqwYBlty9qcYa3muBE5aQx53sOwN5GbJP9dDAjkLebbJ5trIFnGwO8BYrPnyTGxzP40EQ18JEBYpzgiwD0RYvPmzYgUHkiFO@b12@cY9lPq6Jt9IDb9IDO@lBK90iagMV5If6Buh4G8h18GUD90K7NmD@N2Wlaah0qUJOlwqq@hbdJ1@DNYIwSZM2wGfrprSkcp1wupMQ2Er5aU/rWykfd/KsBXydfm@l2/Idtlt@TeUO7Ofd8vFK2Q0kkDMY7EcWX0lpUJHkT9by4zqFaFgaj1WysmN7E7GzOqW9IGKrkwCoCXwzO3bbs/QGi491NA7pM66z08@uoL0k9cnzmgzrbUBvOtaePrLFJVKmjzBuQUYSKIckf9xCQXCioNFOzz1zMi/tzMsttAj10SmWck4K3e3gULXXXTyNbt2/4I/T2XeJc@AO9id@sChfWJW3nrTYZRBRuh9d@9m0q01MfSpYkXalvjKKbMpevsa4X0lUVJyB8kPUFOsyBet5EFGdKv2Paz2xrSgcTfGG7@sUm9MbANYR3/eaEBNfqP8f)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)

### Explanation

The hard part about adding clang was separating from gcc while not using any macros that are defined in clang but not gcc (as @Chance mentioned in answer #45, that isn't against the rules but it is against the spirit of the no version checks rule). 
The trick used to separate clang was gcc is they evaluate function arguments in different orders (at least in the simple case with optimaztions off, that is all i checked with): clang evaluates arguments left to right and gcc evaluates them right to left.

```
int z=0;q(int a,int b){return b}main(){q(z++,z++)} \\ q returns 1 in clang, 0 in gcc
```

is the basic form to seperating clang and gcc.

Because I didn't want to completely redo the Prelude parenthesis alignment I decided to add the new code at the end of the previous C/C++ main. I also made the previous main a function y(). g++ didn't like anything besides main being implicit int so that is the reason for the explicit int declarations. I made the function y() of type int rather than void for two reasons, so I could use it in a ternary operator alongside puts and because grass didn't like the v in void.

The main C/C++ line now looks like this:

```
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
```

In case it matters I think clangs default C standard is C11.

#### Cubix/INTERCAL/incident

The Cubix code was somewhat tricky this time because it was getting stuck in an infinite loop in only 3 steps. I did this by making the changing the first `PLEASE` in the INTERCAL to the latin equivalent `PLACET` which allowed me to golf off one piece of Alphuck loop padding allowing the Cubix capsule to be placed in the Incident line as usual. This also had the benifit of detokenizing `LE`. I detokenized some other tokens consisting of parentheses and spaces by shuffling the code around without changing the parenthesis columns in the C/C++ line and the first shell script line.

Answer (score 8):

## 150. [K-on F*ck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/K-on_Fuck), 6882 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        >77*,68*,@'_            )(22)S/ \\7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8    1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111111xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# do           x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRc -BkBkBkLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoO4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6 27""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p se
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclxx"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#s8dggi2M`|$//''         $>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/pppppppeeeeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<>*s*e \)*///Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .002039

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1rc@tIlhj4@cL7D@ZLXkpVJMUHAL4pibqXT5EURVJ8inqUCgQBEiQIQAD4vKWKmd2N9jwcu3a7PdGesae6x97YiVh/mPDuRtgxE7ER66@O@RE1Hyc2tv9B78kE@JIo3Vs9XkgEEpknT548efLkycRBossZg9/@9gAfqKrKi76smsgUDBP1dGkq6H6UWqCPnGSEA0GKwlBJvT8ZC4ppHFMHiEVIUnipB/fIVEeCIi0FHeIDCGm62te5MTIHnIkEg@c0wUDqxNQmJlLF/dmCCGXH6lDy4ZxjSekDmCnomi6YJD2EUFORuXG3xz1LCT8rUNMh3UAZQf5u/J2JeHU85pSeAZARhDKVVLaUfIYhitClqhsCxsMLhqHiyBhC86zAPwONAyinS2opWT5/lsQy6BxI5zRZmCOua5g6x5uSquAkFtXLzXr1eY4AajVyueexQXThUxWUm/CjnSTSBlVd7U14zB9zIEAy5qkoyYJB8VD3M6TZLenHAXSAdIHrWWCUqOoIZ0HjkYwkxGsa6srcwM8jWQLYHBNDAm4CtIR0eWCguTYGDIY6FrbpMJAiCD1kaAIviRJPSkfC3BQUA2pr@JEEdM8kWUY9QYYMG5J4LyBDE2MryiLAT/VUCsHBa88qsL47FABGEVZMEDRoBcwEFTcacGTFi5nOaRoQCYysA@GmNAbZk0yngQTOkLB0QxZDUHqEf9pa7lXEKdu1RFOJQxzQO9EJbkPQcWP6CV40EHQBUHJryXPNdMkEFmD2JlFV4HTU0AXBvdsHdoqEwlRcgokr4ifNd3rqzFZyTmhGK4ef00zqQA82rooUh/wJdPhwAr@Ew3FCZcsZ9OnwDoctkYem1nQX50aJ75FB390J8JuzXbqvP1GAlQKuyIhWNZPmfBoQ6DOBQJrDQRzyTQN@Td4qGJ0@a4st4bKgetAaqKCglpfUjJ/oOu7WG6ZyI6i0rCp94CdUVp8omB8KijDQBLwKvdKLhClwDcSdtJE6IxxuDCRoNAM3yVZHspQTYSioJ5A9m6Orcg1VnhA4yGmYWACBK5AVYyyIqIVETpJxFkjHqCyqdcGYyCbOM1F6uOVB@Qg9P1qRwas9DDRWp1AcB0hJBPSl8VYPJEQBMDSESqqKk37853/e6/cBT5LnVb1ni2sL9VSeqFGOEAu6CWGBVRVOJmQBnBeXbmWHAqacLPU4ExevLOwiCBGk1Jk6kXtIhQL1mQRda8BNoTuKosCbgiXklub1ojE3svSGZEkuVHzMdaFhSQGkbFJtH/qYhlbiBeqAyIxvPDHFGPJpWeQ06G9cH45dH97fCUCc2@8@OqTp/gkInP@IRMGd8y3JaSV3NKNhcoYq9ShtYQ5UJYB8PHLwCVUTFJdzB4fT69S7Trcf6zOX@0RK8H5RUnouJ8h4Csp1uk/4BH8rHd@fPMu9XSJgmWEsuLcKLt7toEDjkD4xpcecpPi1BWr57NBWmmo8YI7jZP9WNObL87ipFXFABh4sliqWD1BDfkMWBM3F@Fk31hIYbm@1ccK@ij7DYVf4WLr3OA@cnu2qEwxQ052K4r7akFSstWRtgMcWYIpiaKC9dSy6PAfCY2AlbsLo70VdItZE84NiISpxJjh1AXVBj67EiPRIq8fh/D6sJ20Mmx60gtvt0EJvqz@DLoAubRovlLKszqBgQhsevkCDKLhwrg9NBJmtCiWtClklkpjdqo0U0CsYW1dAMV9Xgr6Aex2odlv0t@oI4MGABQPYrL6ypYLG3AKw8NaQuOk3SBKhS41BS@gLxAtY9YAOEqxxBRcyId3QALsHW0CMLxAO73a1Fz3N1Omk7wZ09ZJ@s0Phym/3KaxvkCjMkMwp/QnXx6aXAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30fNghkT57DPUbA@rw4/OyyVhij65bZWBdb7WePSJyWMnYxpdPBp2KONt8RD1JB@0kL56XDgDTZ4U7vsUgOwR863iFhJUhAEImzAV@YoJyA0GeDSR@ALKLqVMs9WiNRc@Lh6jt0kHB@8R10ZgY9uzrAOWn11GYjFdR@HCLvsQDYyxGdbYTQRp/O@JtzJwx3oNYXZMI48FWrJ/m/CB7n8E5VhV1D1Jg5BotBtlNsdoBDLI6NgZh/FpZX6Szri3EdRNBm4H2gJ4P8jcwTc04huFCMgeTrh8khW7oi4JZUbCw0Ka@kEzVCndltQvq2YD@Sa9KoPlJV5o/qxCJW7fh0KCmYIeJBkrAAP44AalzOUUDFCeJT2PgrSQHUeAEhXV2ACAB8gOjXKJBVHIOlEp9ofAuh590JT90OocXOXDHdbghgHOt@ZJWx1gLoTaxD7DBl9JBc4mgrWzdT1Q/t3fEW48BxLxzOv1DVVJcn5zv3793HjvPQMO/f/8BQqc49AGHPBD6QEI@EsJwfhwiObwkhFNvSQ4cd@98ul1hnrvvcbPN8ei0lDQXd3t8HLz3cresfQ3gqxtUHWg2gPbhC@BxuhMJHHS7HWczqKi/K1q1r1mc7RFpqAlKnxLmmqqbqFzJZB@qyUY@4aAnhk7LUpdWYHx9GEMPhrmMY09@mJSsskOwpqpmgjQYjifQOQCyJ32UqU6gz8P8QxpLZoHMfmQFC/am0VapaSh3g6AqCSZlj0YbWccToU3bQD0IfGF7TiTq6nit4QxK4AcqchwGHdiW35nX4mHfTg3h1Ik9q92Kj@L4MZ6R@nmqz/PIp1q360gbMIYB8SzVD5M5qu/xYEgya11H2pBxghLPXP16dxX5iWWecPx62ro1jmxj3Jf@eqY1cpYgN5SJoW1V7hMbIPFTUxRxF11HB0n0CKa@WAMSDu@ZrdvgEQzbU7uCPI@EfIIs@s350o@VSyREWRfk670GsScvNV/uy0CZoCl8c/FZAqdTFoUNGPFKMMFBJckgixvbQkGtu9Md5bC6e3B3LHNsUgIbw3O/tezYxkJEH8RppGLlugk9gGkY3kEBk/2XOUXJGJDTDugLil6mkNzGuCuS0x6AY9sCgw6ElwMwS4p4MomNQFVFijAjYGQsIciAVZLC0TVywaPKPnp2x8cdYrqCOIEJJt2VFBz@DJgvHiOQYrcrvQYKfMGkr657wPRJdx/bQLgGL0wotMN4c6KbstCzr//193vQAC@bZ8AtYGLEj9aBB@Abbiqf@Gpr2VnxDTntb1kCM5zIEkfYQEKfQ8lzePLKyevAftRYgSOfb8Dp0LiLVeOCcOIT9PQ35MyiXBfkSU9YXfcXQli8a6hZuRVpTGoEV2x1klH3lezPzEwrP57867LK9QgWa1FGEjatbbWLMOf6UDl6SyOBPv0COlfWINqswoDZY06sM154@Vy7Shr@7efK8a6QMWGuywowaeW60it8xGREXpNsq8NgQ8UnytzICj7g4P7KWtXRpX4fDDT7@hoYWOMwYdI4XqBn5PKGWKyGDkTMAu4tnLpsnV8DWa05rwOvAUJVZXL6KcJHxIGHHoJlBy9/@rbYJD1jrMx1F9igG/x0KcIFkjEZlEyC93iYIB6e1/PlzUKrpr2eH9sTJH88vj@3tSZLEPCqKArC53oujD7SmJN9gd5W8FVFvDKAN6E9oENuyoFpLHMGCIlps1mYQrOQ01uCiwcUHovLJvSG2G7IWS2LvDaz3uTRJF6VJUMjzb26eU0jPp@TbNDgVXdy2mTFdy/524NpAB6sfevQ/k6t8iae3b4iR1@gpKyJJZ66bwmGX32Nd7w6w79XzYSBOhWs8/6Ba7mXqi9QQT6ZSAZMLV9m7/GfE1e8TEpO@7k42kuVyct744/RparqA0ExUMDPYDNHIWv7MGzLsjXTbRQqr8u0Icmqgerk/BYvYPpgGNZ5vzRvs03iFB8/sPrYOrw/216iyCCHkuT8SuNycl@VI7E@zcHpVQmY6CLW9Pb1SzXcWkOx7Gc11NroURXWvr6q2kfw/znhIKu2Ol7M2Aq@YUvtU2f2JPj1CsK8AK9Q7q9cjomRnH7amvO91gA6P5hxi9X1dxg9XuPuavTQFsRkBpsOZ4jHIGDqlhn9u5QWeru03pfpqBdoo5@rxFbjjmQBNDY5v2hSFGDYn5iDZZgv11iiPBEmwl4NUukOBfys9w3d8eVEMXY1Du1VEhqYhx/orqGW9oTwi6jG4zm@e1PhcLIEnfyz1sxeVaOBna3hCXQVAlUceJmxr0y0ncbd4l1totTe5txAW/VstbdDJE75qRop9nmbaccUNwTye81sz45VmPaqY7AhlC9ofxspWVCyzjuIScwG81DCa1v6m3iP0XrVE@xXsEegVaWR4cMLZF@meAKvzdcJcDwOMzJFMBf4/Bq39ynSrqrKP6V1QJ/2JGymgfGJPRs@10ovbB97ARxtViYMvMrRFV9bk7DGGnvyCNzDE@VXG7oKVTLJ4PAlrfxixfCNUWtr/fBzc0gYscnCj6Hzq/Br9NZw52b9MX/0TYJXq2L0KvAWsrg/@CX2kbYyesnyLF7StRZxN64ZB8/0j7YATkk9n8EPhLFAbt@w@LnecGKsLq8CzVX825Psp8kC6yv5NAk6vILPOwvGWyaRqSqCQZuc3hfwXEUWOLBGrdjXlOxq3XYvcwtjri/kPitZm2UH/GiU16Wd4P4FiGPraQUP2T6jRqxpoKqMhIWxuu43lhc8tOdk/Ca2fZ2cx6ubn@3VfnrvWvVnbD5loA6UgTDQSc9Y373WN0AiTcvL661KAP0DzhjhZ8FEIW3meANjm7uyKstfwl2sEC31qKr7F16z2AerB1l/Et4F14UE@/LZNToYtwmTyAD@Wt8ZCBMYngzVVDXBR@5eA5XxCo913r@WXKg4DdSWBL2Ha4JlcQxFS11ZQDMJSBga208H9q8edWWVw@4Gb1jwwJnV9UvWo3hV32/JnXOqCcbp2yNujtDzuXE5JZnYNaD/GcCd5ukKnKlII9ru3/btfjne1bakahLyZXC0X5aAGfrCj1s5sZ1ex5fC/p4tlWzvzDerlZ7o@uLzUmkOJtaSPg68trRiP0LaS066Xvq8QrQfNr1EYD9/JP5qa5cGw2s72kGcpNtuVcbad/GgoPC6QBwcVg@80QF2u5iMJzJnqrofETiXi/N43G7KyoSXMfoKgK2giPcYdimxHNMMJEuGSWAlEd3eosNP82PmmH1CCeQ4dqD7ewsrcW7IzjXi9lWzst4ecveJQ6fP5zx03inHiHESUEGGWeVeUG4HTpTIxaJzU3WkcGPixYLDq5qeWK4yxoB4o4Hc9qAnNcEsIktgqm45fFheRQ387OO//FXPdtKDcdBAY8mAWURfwY6l6lgYqLMPVrl26UlN47CTH8YxG@DFfVy6L51EBugBGPeJb546Q81cI2a7@tiur3BTxY29RYXVqNgiww5optVoFjU9VbCkxi54nWtVKV6VJ2MFtE/PHBh@VAedJBBXovXDXwhhMMXUsQrueVEB9QS86tzDhBGrQ1bVEXmqjSn5L39lOThBooRFCIdXxRP/xq0SEbakiFcRz6sToHqFZCnoqg3iwkyGkW@CDXqQecGKdyN@wBHPK5BE38rvCBdj@R6lk3XkyyIn9s/F3gwnkug6TNbOW7fMfeJ7NKaF//r7tPuTzTfHV75oxHB40Qrk5AnL1XZyGJI3qU7kOJw77GphT1Di@LgWKts93IXDpLlWfkRj4kRK5E6YET8i8nhewQM79s5UDOgfcOsmqK1Okzh0TSzr0Vc3URg7MYNBxkHIcjsl/njYJwZnOZyj79AAy4qPR2yYgTuLITJ2wxonUqsnh8Hth7t0RuhOyIOOacAfCCZIdQ4fEqdnJKQLPRV7Rd5@czcPML67eTR7Txsr5tzdzb9iAtfAPRUGtsOvadyBsuXMp0P/GfPddwa3QA7Hk/PEetgNvfzwU7VQzdYbyUazDtx8sip7kFP1MbfRFFgWNJnjofvIxN0U2KJLgvF57bHWIOs7AHe50CGHTrFju9u9TliD2qx2@ByHVnANAhbedu7PZN@X3xC20l8C2JpJlJCtRVGVCJItM05jW4N6V7KF2wV39wno7BVHsOfBHlVIeORACeCSD7j0hTxCL2tpteAHEgHN@HlGvY1jHwrg1QbiJQBm0rosXF8r3arc3so//TeosQbj2j@2xgTHmzXGEG/VGAA32UiOXLJQatayu5lAnDbvFoAVreNXTETStywvZUu6VNsjdqWZiAFq2J5va91qoKlkEAMVy5uIRwaY45HuSJ53Gli7IKzI/CgpG6DJez1QTd2FiTUbqHQ/8XGxHF18CnIcALP864HWixwUhjUSLz0jQXPNeNBi31qZDwkcwWxQezy57wT6x3/@55b39p0J4T@yw3MmBXd/Yt@JEP5nqxSWhbt/sb4LwN3PrbtvaMzKl76qVm3WTMQMbBWqyCA2NGbRmJtv1R6PbXjslBSw@6Qx8HpKWIfBrWptOLPB47ptAeehuYDtWEljvUzKE/R7F/Y0PKZpbIrgVQ8/8agQ5jyxronj4eME@93DUEJHwpEQC0an4JuuEPokC6FPsxC63ccgldRU0hLfdnl0enqKHAbPyUIicmKxnD7kvgk6vl0TegiwlGW13CLIA1k2OSDtzM7mOuQ8rBtnxZ3TyTrR/QkYJFYLwpjmIgEAceNoxeaHAwZN1WYViIcizE2i@BcrawxMIYU4kAnW2xcrRD5AZOHG7uHPpXzzoB47MG3JvX@7GRxtDFbHYMeOfUJ2@w26M@@Ue/stAQQC86s9IqdA@I/3vDqwlp7kS6d113OXc1wb9LGuqNh5IwfUIleADgRpNuLe6lMOGxXQi3vQd4AS@gz0QV6QhqpmJNPZQrFSrb9wuiaQzudgTuQ8O/Xc@fze2/t1wPlM6ldMTeXo@mUqt2LlNlWb9U8MsVkEfU7mvtKeU/pK6W3LQ@Jl2SThRUEs86WIyYKDL0eeE7zEvkmltwDT1hPcF6W63J@ebu9Pz@6UgxfFf7fvfZQD/xEWLgjdGeRtFCfao3MKK7@PBn7p0PCvHAkDjs3bVmtnS@t@E/262/T6FcaN7/TKwwT7TQfO6J4wpZWJLFP@V3xPoO5@2iqKOA5bhK3oBV2zIpXFpG4K5KkXa9jb1CC7Li/ftrT9R9dMqlgTWfJeCKfAHEaXeAvaIAramu6SlxhgwlMwN3MkmHfhdUcyFVyQaQ@oivXz8J5EVt84feX7uU6pC2PJ11jRgxXHxhcaFBn28R1A3WSpe8Ilbudo7Uf5lpu039BkyXRh/@S5H08noTYuN64AeyoL2L35NH5v@1Kjlcuzh3hNVyfAr6qqoc0UPiOsQjWYxaHMBJCDGAioOBkDnEguNQGPEgIqqz7IDHx0roi4hVJcdh38414YSvcPhHlP6sNI43J7QSV9xbIbf2vO7YGptxP0sMWqc/ygf5sxP8lHfItj3C3nl5SeMHfh94GO7zF3IN45a0@dbscLGSCO6rbXeu@5x/pKWXCm3Ws33t7PFEI8vlYEu30nHvcPDAr7ucIMBEqsm3oJgjCGusQxpyHXhLj8G8iPyK3rzqV4DVN3I98ZHs9mSEEeD5m7wIUk@BHJKZKQJOOVNRd@Uc5FJ6Cdcayh9PBlKWnolvX77yFMCnGjQ7z6kAZzA8/b3RSYppDlmKCFARj@jjFFM5ilYYqs6yEplsJLBzpA7U0mHbk/IB0QeEFqjc6@RhttsOmBFlfj8WO7NXbVYRyBWJzu0RiAdo@aW9mmwF/bWRG4hpUYQKVhUiqBQvl4ISgK9FcXyMwYeifiJiBkutu7etvbu3kBkJRwYJGYt70fgdDdFwOzzk@yCvbMIX1CZsAnTzDuf3uHB37RHvoX9O/Rfvrkk@tQTixoMMbcZ67DQYL1BI88nkPlyHWoYHPk66/xxPnpEKydB7/D75gDkO9Qdp@APIN1lDhUTg65U9dhLxE4Ijng1uNxf4IM3xu0/9Mh90Qffg3WhBdidKt3ug4NN@4OjN/PPgF9uIcc0l6QmU8uB3KQd7Vx8YeSx4Np8B8@YAK@p@/qHjKu3NVpMkc/sY1cuj9eqZFdW2XdEi/ePbcYaEcfrzV6mHixWw@4HlbA2@8F7knbZx/99rcHbASmWx8iQZfq@RBmTjzOMHviPEAHHx30kUN3fLrL@KZI8DlvOTHgf7yvjqrVa/edC2TTeZCuONiQ45sjmjqgj5jvojT97bffghGKbs/8Z/57963PeX/rWk2kzqLRI28kduT96HzYnrm5XYGAG1h1dxfluCNPKPBROcni4@/@j7/75d/9gvz9kvz@RpIkzej14KcO0Agt4RiJCP@T8LK3FeZwuCsuXWC/g1mXwCL3Dg626nSGg876N/iNlw/v4Y/8w7G@xef3JMaOJiAvj/eIOjjjD5YHLMseLMjfAw6TY24fvvmbB82ygbt3eCODyPuP74B3goccx8cfNyyiHdGYQ1VJzABKCCP1ABv4m2Puwwd1MG9w@A81uvivZuK/1gj/1Xj8h3ypEf4rLfHfPoKog@8TCc@bB9oT5/c/rELUwben3yb@EQeuD3UAs52Ds7P7pyeP79b/jefkxP4HPXGyvsOHFQIC7j0@z@nt6an/7Gx@5rs/u6UOPgFLnqiDgAPE@e6IOkjMT2uEytvM2ao2O0cJYk5997fVEhjqDW/g1HcQyCXT3kC9mTpg4S68ucWJQXxbyyYzlSZAV0vZZD17Xmhlm1WIN@4fzj5@9PihaT4Cf87ugaL5V54zT8I0TXTzcORHX3A87AlZt9RB5mzepH2nQHSJOqiRknz@h7P776iD24Nbl@eD5wMjM1OGHbGjS7Wy@a9U5pAgzZmhqjMDZsD2QGYRIzSZBbOYM2O1wvYgKMAfM4agxIhzps8ojMKykD9UiVQ@7iB85X9cUS8rKuBTIa85Z0yMmhHh2q9ULgGjCKUP4U9iGGYOZM6ZKfwzstWLvnlgsIpg7u6oW@T4VgAF42edfsbpjzid0n04oj1@egpEHm@JFRKO398Kc8m8dyCv8@HuNh6PO@9PDmjj7o62VK8jEHKcYJCnp4eHTLKRfHig8fLN/PTQ89Hj@whH4sxzal8@HPTOTj7cHfuwcFsC7n84oE8/3J0FfTgc8QC/AxB3Snt@4rFBCdf3d5TTNWu32/jXnk1nVogErLi79joVn9o0RFkhHAUHBqX35d8NzF/Kl8t1G77/9OR2u@@cJ06LTy4XEsBydznYu3lARAGHm5j0cRgP2SC2uiJh99lZJAz3kZjb52JIspXlzqFp2p3DT5YI/MRvK5FI6jq3IEAhGJLvHJz@cOe4DdwnEvEwiQ774hGk6r540O1wu79hT0/tMgJuiHY45w5Vd6JPT9t/rk9Ppy5yuPGf240j7fOZ2wXJ7jDczT@55qeuUxeOgyic69PTGQ4SuE8QunW5791PT1YcnF3uUwvnmRvYhtdB/hv@qwYyNOQ8eDrAppSCQmG3q7sQ3KGIK@aJ23@J91ABlyPoDEK9HE7OeXv78Sh4FA3dfrg/8h/hn@v07ux@jwp3wwAOHWYl4An2ALOPOvCf1BxswOHEAn@Cn4CosuCX1T4Kxk/A1oyfUAeQzQHHAcgjcqHTs9O1kGyGGvcZ9MhPiHANue@R@@kTCI6VCKaWy35acXc3ZxgywKOTbuLw0wH3dELwoyfHCtyWP4Lf5Twhj7McnxyHnH7L3jueHIefuk/YJj1i3cT0CYdOTo5CVjgagzB75LZWaMF2OVmHIUUwOJ509JMDLB9OYKIbapXoCn1JATt0uwN4wuHwezoAl/lXkWxgfmQfZ0d7jlgg5jnyfLw9AhMIN8U9if3uPXWCnxVZD6YcPofVjVAsTog4QIYRR6DPToXDqme@@jvKHFkhFv@y7w0KplNdEJEZijIwwMv45RVVFN9b8TAvRF1BANNckGW8uomnTTB7kHszmKq/pw6gDYEqSIZjXOWEiSDMJpOZsD7SknHMDYcw68fHj7/62Y@/@h9//PXPf/z1z3789S9/88Mvfwa/v4Lfz63rz/9DPIzPv/nhX/wvP/7FryHyb@D3n@H3n37zw7/@fetH7v8Wfv/XVtzf2r8tOOtHAa4/@c0Pv/jL3/zwz/4Mfv/W/v3Z89@Pf/ofrf//2/7DwV//@Kd/i0/2zc9@Tv3DX/8K///ir//hP/8K//@v/@4f/vpf/cOf/HsS@HMr8P/82/9gnf/@D3729//9v/z7P/jhlfPP3jz/8AXxP/z/EPPldH4Jni@p10@N@eF3oucfw41NKSBQv/zjH//1H4Kc/ikO/1MIwz/y@KzDYwP8EY787pBhwMy5@24b8juaBdsD0VuRf4S@u8Me0ewGEvD/m@9oBmwkxoJc49yG/OPf/PAv/xJiv/uIIM6G/MNVdlvf7ECu6cT2u1XWHwHwX2zB/NGPv/r9H//yf/jxV3/@46/@hGIR3kPtPXpPBRC@4hOOJAESmh9R4SCotVWY3YSDIRIOw3mfqYkfBX74uBNl4T7aB0wAP5D093stV1zG0Yq2fYW9X@Xfi@ED@gjJYLEQo2WOz/gGYnCYDHXksoqa24Dk3oKx77dyWjHWPdrKvhuPI7cyri77oq0EUuQKCNnI5nahaIPerga1oswCnr@IoJBdPYqKomYVTrXCeb6xdW1kk@k8FUGpSjnz7BK2gcKolM011rdRK3WVNbxG0cmWSs9v7UtHPT5OfM@GohRc4W6CeA4PQGS7lDnZ0Mx/egqiTlFnn3ynp9RZPduAhEYFsQHGT51do7kfVatXvifqDK/fJayBkQ1FPvkMg6LwqPkehaNer9/vhxO@eslBrv7Db1Yg7OuzpQMHy7BhhyOCAlGHA4ZG3wfHQkADNEZBdKIBvdQlfo4VZy0HJAmjhJAuxLHLBQy1M4V4vHTxjjsT7fVIuOAoHNSl/sBE5kxdAxiGAZb42kZf2edrO72NuhyHfz/1gBKE7cN8O8K0yiBxL1Lkl@BUHiyOMd76AjtLmnhBRxIRQ/lxSwUC8Vg4Fg8GYt5YPBYKs5Fw2MsGvGw0Fo0zXmB8jI3EwnHWGwvFg6FQKO6Fpg/Ho9SBoPQkkaZh3s3CBBxfJYXHL2mf4rfdVf/gjDroCSJ2zkFzV8@NDnrriEkMOYKxOwZBRgcbofCD8qN5AiZw2IUgyCLWQTk4xKODXC7N5HIORwrfgCZn0ozD0cM34RjDRFMOh0BS0rEgE4BMA3yXjTD4jReHhG/SyVwOYxjim0AM43A4RlaKdSOvbqIApuCbYBAjQA7H4xodA8hVi6IYyWVaNwyTSjscE4u8GPwBXNK6CxFis/gGJ@BMOSslDWkOx/kqEwxQDkfNgrOLyq/qm0w6HAXrJpnEKIqk8mGrUhf4JkkOyKTDHQivw9GHQF8Ha9Lh6EIQi7DDwUOIX3AQN4YQ9hBXTM7hWFj1wDVxOOYEmuNHDsfDKh7KAXryeW5g9oS@dSx068pDUgGSpPkkm@uen3f7/a6@SGbPaySpWMxzw8VE7/a7dsbuAxwqzgVJo/Hi@SHgpIcHTt6fdAFJyrOkh8WDQCh84B6BMvvo44LGD0WcVISkfcthNkI4xgDcxUdqDNcU17WSVgdJItd5t@s4AaGlcO9BC5f7E1mccCFDWgqgdFyMdwJz5vCHScwRiTqOj@Dq@OAIQnDuQowTJk0O553D4b6N339wRMOOY@eHDz7n1@wH5IjGHceOaNSB3Ce6YE50BQVOnnA5ywRzgq@PLnzmvPjcxZOvTzZc9@QJq1@YsX16dC09Cda7dH/AhMEcPxByuI@B0JMnmj7FvR93V7iilcomD1wALubwgR5HawBLTaz7OfL5QIkj@IEtg9O1hFVnlyPuwjNMICgev3OQOaG1FO5yOqMBp9PtPAEk75HDDTNDi05MO6FvVXus46H28YBjVXlX3AdTZeSLA@UvaNFHx4bJ6fihCCnqGDkicQeOxrt4xl@MIR@9PtZ7fNQNn579kxfHf/dP9h37Y/FBWaNchKUOnqgefs07FEcneIb9iXr69HR6Zhd6gRYLzuNb0fA1Qn3PIXXoxCxwBncWa5KJZL@WXE2ck2nqwBdUQ@rB4eEhdXDaOHMEHRX/w3oh6owmK5l3eJkTLwv67x5O33t@p1Uqn//s42o9FginKV3APoI9vIeotVoUC@Mm6SPjwPM7HlAIlQCc1AlefnAc4L7Hy9D/ovitVqtCp98fkNUkVP0kThTykPj4Ej8SdHHHdbLzxu09SM33ZUn@FAv6zshDFSzVIBxPWj3@TfSb2DeXzUqzkvvIHMeOY4STd3d283tZJ@skLfPwEQYwqZalDozv1DD7vVI8OTjWnMGQM7hujrvEgVV3Nuo@OAtE/Qa3OLi3/Z1dIYi8t55/BdiD9u4x27mZkoVoKCr2e71@Xwr83uW33x3StNO5Lurw7NMXHE@3p6dPp/h4sgP49PT0dPrin1w2xyswm/TfTWz8Dwf33/tOrf9TOKUrFnMckbDDjT3YjW8evnk4AHUSR45A2IFnDLS1NKGtbJMjhfwJxhH@@2YTcQTZj9Z3wukZJAvozn1E0/RVAIyWeDwSixxQv6Xpt9w5IHX9fFMUBN2YjPc94Ezq0iWHH/4q64ecELicLAUdrqvdSFfmDcL2DX6Cjw2c7Tjb5tmKIpv47sYtDBq7m@JYMI/xdq9kN2kkYl3qwut2JnEbREd4C2XsVe@mPlHvANeEN4mnKpxOKOoddpnEt64VnBd9bZhu7CTGuKl37@yRwTD9hvmAkeNMdqSPPaGeKMwertczEH72THy@LFd8Djsgqpr13qS8QFYmg4xwlqVGvOhxuVsEHyHRogJqc4RIiYRyXDmr@HcWWHciYlJyhVIW8qAEEokPg53boXfxZnmkeu9Ft104YiAKY8HghFMEHAMCOoh0EdzuMfb3510E0oNYnC4SXwiAAsPVSyjxItHOeItv7yE7Ri/ysmoAYqt0l1UDdPRgF2vXYTXg4koAC3HtyIhGBma9z3vt1sP7Cd3eu9GnlVexC6eiUxTYuD3buKAxrH2uSUZ@3LMEh@xCaLOZYGPvvdC0J5Z3qmsNZ8dsGPVEHZne8YnVVNoJdeHi3Z/ws/KT78dff81/o92O70/c44SJrx7PGIbXkUuyQI7MxDgB4qHdSvcn5q3HI90nxu4LF753n4zBDnmiRIvZhtuuG9RcSQAt2J/GcHuXt4rve@Xem7tVPEDyxHt0k1h6uQTjncNPAttE9j4mWLseUKaZWHqUE@4Ufvix/Y7nL9gYHu5kJwpnGbnkxPKWu08AP2TI6PHkoDJAp3Erezz3bihchsSXGU/kr7/mPPLZ/ET2@dwY6pvgh9ytCYF7TwLfH7u40/mH5e0E8h@74JqAYmQ3EA/5bF4/rWkH@k6Ax1abbki3aJxj8uZA3jiROLr5cHRzlHj/fnk7943vvRb7j5mNNGDi55j4ky3PatfRjRs9YwlZgXc5vpKOv/IfGcjhlTweYLJX28ppUXh0Aymax7Oi@gnrS7L97solBEuY7Q1s7VZIdiojz2zILsEG2Rnd7OH3IiBv0uAlyQa3XmjRJJgsc3g/Xy9SVMXHEQicZm8HjhPv5h8@UKuibQdUKBkrl66AODzpJrvB6vhxANla3npZ7XP6dZ8aXunc9VyzXrjJIpjWBiNb3ZWoJtLhDJ2/xSBYDXxink4sjWW5HYOyIdoDYIj2wHA@rEUwk2w9YUMm7ERorVUDQS6sJ0TrZT280Z2B9RO2gtc9H1SIRQZ05j1kSN5hgugmkCcJQkg6JeVBALoK9Q4qgWnAdZDu0RkoMvT118i@PU3AVD2KxwIMhuGGHhYDvaAUCv8CSgEHpnIIMor1ISkEaHuHU7Bb/U5BoX9cQfZbMS7I4Bl6rZdj/OTlGNdEMax3wjDf3BYZuC3evRt6EiGbIPgn0wvID2lPvz2wh/tjlK5cVpuNbO0yWYczzI5imx3Hj9d7U7/YkVbDO812JYW4hvNcjRU6RR4hF5isJt6KDO8830PFZgkFAuWMF28cAqw/sBbTYEA9XmMSDLIpo@FX9T49k0YSvfuNC7xLOPFCJ1/U8K22DMfkkMFZ3ryptnlRzcALXjCY27sd7Hy0YCwYhr3Rrm/17QLyfQbyzt4Yv3oGvdDemJc4@K18lIhHHH5i5SV@lrrUl8iG9AMLwU5@soeqaWUn/YPCG@r2OJPDEk3FYwxzjBgvDrCrQGAVCK4CoVUgvApEVoHoKhBbBeJ2gF1hZi3MMJUNBiObYHQTjG2C8XUwxGyCGwyhwCYY3ARDm2B4E9yUFlqXFokRvOhgxU3SdQUdp7Gh2CoNv4iqmCQyDGjY55EhIDTwAhKyh15EQnmx3chonLELKtAVDBQIRDb3oH1WsAmXRZXXosNrlWzd2ZEwVlHWFI0IbFbXQStl53gHcRA69zHCb95QFKhdxMsCB8aAYIKVksiB/AvuY@uNVH1xvHn7BmNIsOt7yI532IU8LNkM3xKfPcmBfckWtsBebNYbv2jNmK1Xl2wiLSqPd0ZaC2NoJ24b63usYDFHX4EIWBC4DXbfdVqV2dAne4sMvl3kDsK9Rb4gysIb3pcL88ZFkCdWWcn4T7AlVuVZdopAWhvMAPvLJ0QGnjUofjU58Yk9dvzmhz/739BvfvjFr9GPf/Hr//c//c84/B/x6X8HmwUF1gA//wU@/Rt8@lf49Bf49KdbmQh88Njx45/9Cm7/p3@PfvzZL6ykf/mXDm9ojQhScNQm5y//KT79IT79nw5veA34yz@2AHEWh/eJ2jGtXAD1879BCErDWNbI/uyvEHJ4wMBw2ZJ3a/Xx@60XGS0EazbcktD983TrzA90zHbG7XEAXvuO3dx5cAO4t5DrHP6Ux6bvgTljucVjLc1z/AC/rGZHqQa2f3hswqiGvw/yNuuB0WOvajih9n@AjpHTg2EgmryRnbB0uF1/u96OTSqG9ThooA7vjm2jwmH3mhKY3lIg32QmsDD8eNpCZqSsJSM2f8v4U0GrAcSxkizJdLFuyi5rlRsmPcj@4gL8b6a6WGjxMGS90Uy@fELZb1OxWwXuqJtnzQalPI@BKePmHcftrCRCGGvQJJBtzW/MWHxDuOB9jm7Tcna3yVZyzzoMPrpgYo62NdK6oARyOD4Dizltw7uxxRXchbfotQFumePg/c4bk/uAHdfX1w5qK47BMqT3XATDVqUslbFOYneTAltJga0koNnCSXRNOBB4RgMZOLBe3H072Mq2paJ2s22EC/ecVTtgMmAuaC1mekV5YgwSL1ETjbyr7F4i30LJ3ifsfnKnEJ1zhhzuFxkA526exPO23I@aeQHzsqH258Tc3onZaa3XMe3k2eoUhHvUcy6tW46N72u53QLfQM3ee76woADzjyzI94UFRcKfL@h5s@K8O@hf5@/n1c5KTaw1/AaZ1fEPdgYoPDT@GYjeRh1hinUSdLlhypO0pzzdmYpcez6tAfH0aqewne9p6Fv7h@FJTFk1BWt54KOmwpRDxVbw1ve49n2Ez/78VV9RdcHYfhNast4VU5z4XXxe7SswqnnxjmWS/bEY/Aje2pRld1xZj2y2FZq2PvGFUVuMwpbnw4OkSObDAxifsujeMBDf@nn8Ao@Twt8Gg9BWftfatK1oLhXvvGi6P4@T2LtWtobEj1wVzU50QiFJBBM6XpBh8oUGHD/CX7kjLMFVJG8bY4u0a7rcmIkDdaz2BUXF2xDg3M/QFza4MUGcphFavIjzIn6LInsS7eK9nNvOevGTs6KLgItzr/MHdhHsMMOL9Oc8xpzV9xT38GpxVrZVefWfTm99m9762/SKkm6Yz2kmkXi1B19/WtFB1wYDAG7ICH6eDK@988gLcnZIWUfjT9ZYGb6YxJ5g8DD8YUqTAJq0wf0iyId3fWfA3Zrw1mv8f7sBV9mzX9p8xJitL0DfjLPY9iNTNINsy6TwggvAC26se14WtxbtzBeWZU90yAzPixxEcSn4PTDomJomKIZjBblC/BmZx75BL@SeOAwlrMQ9NOlTLxoFXm@izENPkLmF0HPZkN4tvKsa1wSuR/TVl1UcKzqi9FTrO0UuxsvumGLkfV0CdPyKyHDeqdv9ulhZINJaesjDOEJh4XX@kYW756oZL4ImrGcgqg4a9IBs6UM2UtIW2sJ6x1@2Po9o61Fr/LFasoy3PvgsQ4AP1sfvWO@mWPdb6rPmWlfpC0aENax/t8r4Nd4VRvwi7cs2/Gks@nxNySrDOlNi1co71slrLS691eJbUrGSScsq@TKR/JzQfbHMbYmahWyjwtI/bQh5gTnNyTLPu7YxWjFvtpiqvNAJOA63mKq8Mqo87FGo65xE05n4yxEJy75wUxIEC3CdwrUFV4wQ5qAPlkCt6obt2tWSF0kZc9qW1WLH3PLYFt3ionv7OeIWFLUK44Xcp3WZ/Ktl8i/K5HfKXPeA3SK3gCh@p0i7FXDzvNUEsiCar2hnnIRn7nB5S23Doaicjp@9fnJKzmPJi5xT5zEoZKfgPM66QCk7e87jDAkYzuM6CYycxxcQ2PQt53fO41W3wAA63JLARxxvq3B8zzuP0y73E0U@irsq1@88XrcpwHywbglHnqzl1a791F9dr6oKgtcyKr0IS4wBFxVX6/beS34M/BNQe588SHyfQIEjAownIDuDxtaIYZUDw4affHXTtW/4OF4tTdnrG5s1FEj3JLYWVbCUTIg@ch44d5WRRRhOJYuPcAUCsd483k8RYl/MzD5Hjl06SChp5N3yCff8xB7ouUj6LQBvL@LIm/yr9tpFYTXgl9GJM79G5wtyVsURirAzgHsPWZip3zrfqBRu62d7rlmtv91CL9cIcCP6ViBWKxG0WzodbDhsm5LCNFXbFRKSip/2Sdt58GF3Siy9z7IRrWD3zFeSSbRdM6wYtju/@63qbOXDpO2oIJx4y9xbvWw9LhBdjJM2um7LUrU6H5CwpXN6ZBMUAYttxg4SOEvdeMlY8dowtMprFUk0166ahMx@/DLmhDOt0jfPZfArmj9t@rrKCSY40IgRbOVcl2LpV/Un2O@qZb@vDOoVE54VsM@w3j@UvjSv3xxln1Eub4p92YA40Ysy7r3G0bqEDcthdrBlmb8lay9MfPxBMcvItwpdY39m7a/Ytp4TfIZvz@cWFi5sJejT3cgRXpgdBV5n1EuLRJ76V0aLH5dk47EqvqZ0U7W3abUqvq@JcQoeo@HykxtY323g7cbD@EgF9Gcst3o5/owreU6x7tt4TX3ryYX11EHFXmLrHQS3IkHdE/@1tYsWRFQeaplKudSBQTcajbpfPorAvRbybsZx6s3HBOtpS8CLN4EiH5fHvhMDVTff3ymOly5lJAKMAY48t7HEz@7jbluXbenzZ30X8lmwWxy1cY023YDb0UrY1OHwkC3ZfLU2s3cdcTaSlXkL/PaS2Rp@aoSlAz/QeXggw9fDA3bOeXiwRzHcNOvHSL89sL9nF9j6QvzBrjcTsbiMFzut4AWAydj6Prm9AGfvoWL5oRwAnoK5yr3ONVFMaeXsgNeH8COqtWeEK8ji1YmCuI4hdGCnDFcghKewgTB@t93KhaHxwidxrbTLeW8ZOngrYUNTFbIZJNlgi5jteGNjY7X0SsieKDOOuIFYpZBX8rcoshyyVs/FyNe9yecDrE@pc4q1hLzijRcJfT954hOIw5RjJGnWHoFr1w/DTTIRgomPFvC4Kwtj/IVtkN09q8mXErTKICf1@yBItP2FBsvBpYE/uu1TRV96tffNAWqR76Tbu7DaPmFkB2R7HRjY6drZvMhAgQhYU3EvcHbzA8ZiNxmENyhiiJMWgYJfFC5RKxjzbuV971q4d6@rXV1YN8b33vWAW9Z6n1PS8dcYppyyxWf7Nc@tpWn7oSXRA1tPLlf7cFH2vmkJ8pzSj33UNJfjwLHanQwHLbcJTuZX2/q48IZSx9Q7hSge7AGGeMu3BgxcBRtt5PGae@2SqqCvUDBAPi8L5RErlRQLOKwnezvYIQ2yYmIt7z5bwTi@6jm@wg8TqXcHWBdasobzr0QZh8l@rBtZRu9tdNYDFdyVrS6wuglv3QRhqvFuT8HvXQ4PYPE43I4dTABvP/14Z2nel1lBKbp/Szd6kXZOTSaTjTGr186T/eQgWevAfYopedrDUJams3m5l8wUuotzNdqYigGm0blKdYOearQ316T8OJ3XspQU6ow9N8F5PB9ahtPBdJJnrsXzkhiKpq/Fa0NIykKcng5HVz2hpnVZ3ZAuypfl2pLONa9a/auheNNuD6NKndJqN6n@1Vy4irWVaasZLxhXQitdNkfloTlhF5VoO9KcKUaq1UgNiovCbDQvRNSOFE5fCdGWqOVn/CKs8fkmdTNtDCL1/GIUZ8e9RTJt9DpRj4fupFP9WJ7v3YjFevqi19fD3fCoHueC03FR1BaDi7zyWBqm61Peow1zhciUUqqF6UwItUddOa/c1FqtbiZVnY1Y40brDUPty4nZjemRYHCSFAbDULgwMfVYKZW8iJqZZKGVk69b5s2iFatSZt5sRJtFPi57phWTD04yTdpgWvOidFGfRfKBhppXinJhWB2dT86rsjYZZUJSpTEO6f3rXFcNBPJX9Wm@U6L0ULHdidWGgViGn/P0RVhVx8FGvFzSL@eT1GNFaKf5ekroRphU@DrLDi8rC74yLdVq7arWbo6jxgUr3@SYIVW55uvJ1ChXGsfYRnlRiJ0X6pN0ujCfdgNiX01Oeu3g5XVkVioLhfYVHcxzE/PSI6UrMj0sFo1Fq3lRuC4bN9CtL4tSSFzMU62ULj5m0sZlrUSX9dGgHhoqPa0VldIqX6wWQmZhlMzP2jfxQmokiNXuSB012nJ7YkqZIZ2jFunRVbMrzHLScsZlQ6XWFT3M1ngzmuwH6/RQFLsjuWIs@@elZb8@6fZ78co5kxEeL3qpVriW1djLnBEqKwuq00iJ0rJ2JbKjajxfuOlmk9KlEk5XBa16np/OA4GOJFZn4SU7vx7mQtKcDzGlSur60nNVDNQ8JU8qVVWDlT4VyOTO2/3whUfNCUu6JHKP0bRHn0xC88wEf1O91FRkfRyWmViu4RlEDb0dv7ycdY3CdS3d5uVl7OZyNIrc1KjracFQ9UCsmEvG6eqI0c@5YblwE5WUXGiWOpez8UJ72YyZ2dJEjuVL/UyxpmcaY/46nu3XF4tRP1YUqqVRkhJimVpt2O23uvNO3agumMsQP@x6sufZ8mMf@nGrngsUm6lIf1ILti4yyrTayHmW6nW7pKXLIzZbjU0ijWhwTE3nxViybiqSljm/jEeuJlIpm8z0m2lWFYTrR/6CHXH1xoKJGVH9Knd9pRkes9FVQ91BKri4uuzQrRvDCOcl6mbejhSSI52/6M3NohFtKAG1csWwV2K5KYenbemxU1WHyTF90bxe0t3ZMjevmrxZH6nhXjQ8Op8bj/ryQr@gYp0hJzfLabU05CMXHWkZpcOs0uikxUu@UwwwyWY/fynk8tP@simMA8P84yTPc7xRTXa653JkOtc8YjA2LVGNcvu6H318ZLpCuROXkqNmrVowAw2OnnTqpfBjqWMYOb5ZkFIhSZlkUp3z0Th9s@Aaxnw5aUS6srio6gEmS83LncsWP1T7Rs644YfL69yNcjkJRK4rQzFq9kbsWGJLLZGJlrWaJ@Opyufd/iLSmghTHixD7aqgsankcFihKuw4Ok0t4oapnBsX5W66mJSSyVIscKUFovlR@jw/70mtZquc73Fq6KabDkYq3T4T6KXK2X41NO5Hq@VoqJSmGt3FVY3tZWISO@Dk9LC4CGnxUiAVoVuzWv5q2BgoZTmdbM/FVJBvqLNomxOVprCMROlLxjMcxItKkglVI1TTzJjNUm4W9CgXhctAdbHgr7vcJMiJjx3Dw3eWg2WlJXCqPCg91thGa1JKS8NhK5LiG0wlVWcmS2PGaaUqFc9UFTZTmk9zs0G9zRhaJq/FuvNyL12tCl2tF9TEbiU5F5lpu31zddWsKOPrq3G@Fu1Wlj1uGG6ZYi1SmZvUI5g8rWmpmevOM6IhDmvTR@V8Prlu0aHm@bjU7E09w/hNZxqUritMqZxqidykcNWPms3yXLssyqJMjwOVPk3NmtXl0hSSarY8u@zMxdZymZRSxiM7v6C50nkhc2164tlcMlNp1DldrlTOS5kkN55dzkrXUY@wrF/2wtLo8YaqKooc0G/qcjTFBI1AM5xZpvnhOTM5T40bxUac1dhmvnV5ecEOZH7MRzuVTKR9ybeTyeLFoihyrWpVq140G1TFo1zf3DToSkMuxcVSodZQw4WpftluR7mZmrzimEJo3J2V5qnZ5WTSHseLno4pcEF1KQhsbSaXaCEPshOjhMm0mi5XjUXgcTl87E8z6nUrntTOI8n0QuxNhemSSWamHtrIzWe9iKTFAo3O/Fzs8Jf9/kUtNQhqU60RSYepYly8VFrd9OAyvhAu8qVWbmIK9V43JHkMRhs2rpJNo8kvpHM@Mpg2jY4MnU/Uwo1UOm7IN5nYhS55mBifovj2JVelS4PwdbnYU2fp@WVrkYEpR4wVq0xYXSitSWyk5C@M1EX78SIW6ze7@REUPBncDHip6Un1usKVKJepm@uL1ihbnbTo4dX1ZbTazHtiy6B@/sirg3MuvmgsKwwjiPH@tDCZB7USHzuPXVR4uTgv15qi0I/UA1fyubKkMkp0wCRFdjadKbRnEU7Fsn0x1SwreqbJ56OCWuVoet6@MSvt69hF4Jy5YurjGRMwLmc0I3YUadEpdzqBHpWaGhdau85Os568mezUhzX@XKbL7VphqS5K2YDRTJbT4sVkttBKC0kP3vCl87Rc5SUWzJJwpN/Qm6Nlatql2uK8lE7FojeBPEiQYcjxWSfECbyh9edDunQ5ycvz4WTU0j3jOV3z3HTm4figNTBovlRqlAuzrB5Wi8ZQoSIRPpBv61rUqD2OF4W0mRm0mnIoHW/1u5V8h75siBfxq3T9JiqEq3ThUYi36xGGL4XbPM3W1PHUhBGJ74@o0oLp6bws6Fx0UnkMZycTT28xnZge7SZ6fhFr90dpdspznmCyqz5y81ZRZqRyVOgblfZsep1rg4WotKZNhcrdNLXghZQX6/lW5XLEVpO1pUmn4m3@OtTv6KyoiNNa0AwXC0I/youZ7M1omMkXHgtMR3xkZqysX10Fc3mWioqelKn2ZLp1pV0pywAnJDuV2OWst0yPB2VRyBcCGb1Ti/TqF5ychWFUeiwxWit3XrrpdeUBLapKpV5jGOomEsi2r2uP7LR3VV021Hle7xeTVTl4LRYUtXrdYjNXOl2OpnJX6WHtJr2IRaq63BUa/VhDGXvOgyrPJZVShIoKUyHVatNNQQqy0fmyy40Emr1pj0axPL2MGEs6qRizYay/jHfPx2z7pqyeNxYj@nw8v6mmrtmJ4GHZKq9RV@ayGj4/b3suFufNQl9uFkSe5saLoZFPTYTirHsVSXpiGtPwZHutwbxU7WvtLB3tdmNsPRhsh8zHXnVhXJWpVqaUD0YzC3MuZkeT8jyW15KR@mLevAqFRjfDeSVWj9TCc3aqjrIpLdcP0@q1EVXmjXw/lxKy4qVoXC67/JiKLCflQi6W9YQFrlPt3DBiln6s92Rz0BcbF9fBeoTmw/lKdXZzk0nS46g4zBbkcxgTZ9zlfFEfdkbdq4oRlCi10vEUIsvIsn5zVe4p1XbxctCd9aPRqp5vDeOTZUerSTWPtmwWuup5pjqWM8trELhILR4eNuVssy1dZ2pMhTIj7eQMbHA2VZIWfboQZi5EhSnOx@fx63E7MuqMWulprTMfDSP1aFidCMuo2X4MT4RmtFMc12m@25kNPIFzSq0vF9fZq5BeKs@0kllVhQsmFijdjJrj7KTpGacvcl0z3Wa0bqBdmk086TBYBbHLVjxQ7l4MU4XR@ZWRvwrEqUZOWkxiw/PIuacKg8lkaFRiLTkgT@k2LbdmU2E0Zrhyhmvp824zV@qVe4EYrXmk6My8iDwWO9UbztRCCk0Zi0hvxnnyWbAgMlInXPe0TI0Zw1yEuZ4GL5R@MGAo1/U6b6bV6KgZjAuhnN5S1NZcHbYC0tV5dDTjpYshlRKWvZDcrLV75fly1ouPQj2uPm0mc9dKO5hWtMHc0NlI/CLQ4h6rYz1YMbVqqcmnlKsxx4kzz1xOZS71@pTq9cvJXjv3OBGnrVAlGUourntMaHIzHbLK8jrbCQyr3eRAnNXaoWVtFkz1zlmlNpa0sR6gmUZLyY5i82ZeuKCKy6ywGMSuUtVWqHkxjI@Ccn9UrzKLUUUS@ZsbY8IWOv3SFdsrhFupq/goLxpJIdqMi8UhPS93KzeRdE8IMZRnUBjTgXSJDxaz1x6zyMvhR2nJls1lXFQW5abUrfenSa3UGzYn5VSeTrGB6fm8Mg7ma3RwwqXGscyF3tFlSsiGk/Nm5TJiDG6SZiukVgPTmHZTlfrXgV51wPFjJhIDHXzZ694smslaalbqlPN1I6n0l4JHn10o54VcLqVQebFdfjQeOVWcJEPNSqlz9XiV1PuNcNc0Cuz8UaAXC6VSTPP8opMsGKNyq1hXClFm3EtdRq8GvZLSVKtS8ILi49HRdZRW6nxxwgihajKUe2yd84@FaaSmjhSTb2RvWLNcA2VXCDcrWmc2XqYHjDgPhrLXRqXf026gtw6XVGCSr3V6NXGozGe1otm6CI7r7Kg1k0cRhdM8oWy8UuHYfhBPwsLXqjJW5Yu@eV0vTy90mh4sIxNBOxcuJKoU0PrJQi1SDHDn551MvMmOH0tCIHYZmiRngUrt0qOEBS1T6I9lJj2qDYUrCaYM7Uh1WGTqZanZv5mkr@OLOrXsdMW4UmzP1Iv0aJYZTYeN5jwI06tGq2QY9dq12StMA91iVO5WBr1GJpe@4tMcZ0QrSjpbGWmTVnc8y4fC1DAXvB5eRotSPzKKFoRF52KixavFZSE9yIc8HaUYMzucKT9W5OFjuWua3ceo1KpfFel2KsorzOMial4P2rRB5WPj7HlIiC4LAzbaVMbTyaRXqSlqYVG9ugQ2RwPBxnmXTmrtq6rZ6uUF/jrfBEu/qAqF@nVRq59f53uTnkLJQRDfNK1fnJeM3HVmdMPOCrVFV2I9o8rFrBKOhsV41zMNj8uDSSYcbkfHxfI0l9H0yPwStH6/uqiWhFr5kmLHl53syFMUWTamXy5b01AtKVxHupczcRYKZ5JzZRCLNZn5VfGcv4p1tcJs3Cyy/St6dhMfGWOuydWSvCpWqNSjFlxk5maWCWcvIvnrK2EYmfWyk0AhOau3CxEzXhbb7dDjrDYbCeUcKzbm01mgmqtcmUooPG9d3YwuoBXCFN@fX2WjwmVI6DHS8iat59Su0uSSDF2kA7Nm68qj9pXHsuAZVQO5oBbJMvMqBzPjm9Sk2It0m0O5fZ7KxwdUL8RnPQ0jUriJPF4/Xkr69dATHYPKiYm16dUlmCRds9kIza/EeIddttKxNtfNLdnsBZ0M5fOTeCEQKJbipQ5l1MNjkJbHWeC6mJEDV9VWIzTxZMqZeW9Qv2nW0rPL2E2HHVfb9WkRT8aCNDMTK8Nac1HOzZuSEMmOalkxRXkKVzOjEtfEWqaV1elqT8yFhqP8ee5cmFzwk3lW8TD9QnMxfZyMhVjxUuYEXcnVzEGSD3Zio@CcL2jJx4sWtchz2SKbjrVi@kjii8Ny0xga07YmSsnQY3juMWvDqnQRztQa18qwOSiXdT59GYgaQmZUH0dumsN5dypke0VKNONTXp6flyOmklrkpOvm5VWxV2cWfDVWLOf0OdOlc491ZmrSzVi92uh3y7pUGsLA6ek0VTUmg0oxB@oVxWmDAjNrJS96sb6RPmdipeK80pTKHuYqWxtmAsZU99CDcSWQWarZYlCcRfu1q4sxo6envYHnohqlb4YpdVamwmYv2OaMUbwmsp1Oi9aytaVhXMaaXc/FlUwLtcBNNJVfso1uUOtNBp1YZ3w@fex0Lh@7rXoemvPaI0Tql49U/@oib0TFOM/2mql0KalONaaoj2tiaFxSO81AR/R05pnC7DFwweSGhS5bLg@WyxRf1NtKLDPuXqa5xbAZa1HBbIXp3QQFrdjMPHZyg8mQT5fmfPBazRue61B5PjnXY9EIG4pPOSPYGo9bnlhSljzR4GAxCKSy00iG7um1NpWteNJtVYVeULuJcGXaCPXKsmk0o416Nl5L59L50kX2WizF6wXu@trTuSqks8lGpHgxGIUuOqyRolOXg2E9QA1L6VGPNs3YRKpLOSN7rmfmg5vR1XjSnUWnJaOzVC64idQfsyKnjdolJRpJXrUewxUmmL2kszdLWQlEw/M41ePFXpGWa6PrdkzK5umOPIAJdAbkf3R9OdF5UTcG8TbU/HKpRNPNSr@l5@VBFSiUuxONF8dxaTQQgjdUja7HctG2fCHylU5tHO10petGMRgVJ3OYv3YyywsxQ0OrNzv1wYS5jmTBdA2FHgvtwfhqWm4ZtXCm1ShVQ1TrsZYR2UK2VGrdmD22XGH6uanZjMbyWZYfp0bl7CLVTRVmOb7ZznuGnkCjx09zraScbfU4Y764YeKMnhSHVGQYuUyJGdachVuiHkoXB5UgJxfUeaUY08a1ajGQKmavRHWkM6mr5OqItBbxsRRe9MVk8rxV6KT7VPIqnRkGWqLB1xTPrEDAUjmZ@@1P3ipE0HWFgFFTVerhTzUZgr3NxckbG0@QnSfw6@07@05gZ5/tjQRE@/1qoAXK8Tqa@A3hY6sQ8mzTjz/jgR8tnjx/tuhjV9sJkAvexwMdkU93iDsPQh06zrwm472kvEUAeeJJnqDg52Dk9eSvjGP4AQ3eFUpgE3mjzkV44/4sbYQjeJ8PvAcoc3@y9cjTxW5TgwmEJuMUEfjpdXyFd1X4GjKSR8DZSs6977E@c7KTH4gzNIXsNOLw@R0kq70rBsa0i8JqTRy/3puBIhuyrB6svfFhMo5mY0wkTvb3QIrX9I5v4/feIz7hQIIpccrYmOiz3qivDqYikpE27M75xfIRoXAI4S2OAl9b@4OykQRNNmeOwjmG4mQ/58PV9pxkO3q8mxfZmBHvBupEaL2X1cl75CYBLz4dO05eSCk6Gq@k0NrkY3wbuU8oCeZkfKvcnygej9v0JEwP63HhiK9Z94k2sT0Rb8178tY@fYQuV6/W4892YN9fVURVVeEHqtNA5KPr2@@ckF3LVh1ozGnb/Wkq8Kaqb8eIWJ648U5HfBmFnxJzz3JK6grOXGgCfnS33pVAVkF@8endJBI6eZmOa/juHd5C48T2ndiuwCdKm3RliT@m3hF@4kfg@HX642N7UxgeYbl9947ESVakRQuSDBdOPlml8qq2sDNLFsjDqi6nWyjPXPjZqtv7JZArqC7I5AP@yJoOYBaIxd4dcASoyaNRt0UVDpcEZf0cFO/j4z7Bu5yg96u01Y4/GB7LDdl358FEEtmlBy6nyAYle2Agt73jBIm9lfBLb8SV4MxpJb0bTsYaef7st@i1OYK/IPugcZK@zuk3Jvjr8C7EYmZIK6JxC@DAE971bcqZwnbTrNoCO76Rl69wfTC@KvkMEBDMc/jT1qAb8csHGF9PJXneWZ8odiFTtRwrLTLsvKQabrupgXF463Sn5jxGxA/uBKLII9GTrdQhpOK6vpI8huQxZw5eSR5g3BPjtWQdkvGHi19JliDZeidyf7oK6daT/lcATOzlCeL6YKoPJifJLmtDD7wVyJOlsF3I41kxdi0CyGoYqz128yN7axT03modS9h2xAv6JxErCwCLtMvuPPh@Iy0kFe8s77LkYqtMiyfoE/psYbZzJLD4gZQEaheX7z7awY@2CID@B6oUvUxfFW619rqiO/Ljh2Gnj1sbmBVE3333FmW2IO7KH3u/kj6rhbAf7lYNLW5t8FjfVd20q5VpaWfan8feOmZbu618JDb1WHXKwEaFWH1r069FSelBGYD4/XY0dnlyow@bmFvjHh2vtceGj1a3@DwfAy@kB3tEkR7pRd1NkP9yrnJY7iEnByNyd6Ms8D5h3MkLdhpraN8u9P9X3NWutZEj69/pq1CaJNhJ@4skZ@dgYGLAEO/ytbZJhocwxNgN9MR2e9024M3wY8@PcwPnAs7F7YXMqbdKUnf7A5jZ8zw7eQZ3t6RSqVQqlUpS1QblttSc4rN2imf0KP29jX1aa5YIPx7UTJuyCNo2qYYbGsE56LWkX5MyQYC9WF6V74gCG6SBBQuAiT@9cwIwWiMcMLMZMW7mxKCflzupJOeLK@88PmIuWe5jMhlh9RQ6/T8MLhBOT9ljBMZLiyQ1hzQz2W27Qa@N6SE31TyR9PMbdyqXmpd/XAaOapafmOt@pFlyVRWVddxUVvePy6E/Rpnvcfel9J0os1hWmE43nPgUFrxfQOhHmSzdhJUzlaI4UGDJ8MiUxE4I509K8dH6c/PFHLuUsb1QAwNW5XQ6cBaAJoEU5WQpT@tcG7Ho1N4Xz0dGufFiLQzxaIUrSGUvO0lxjuXcDk/eya/WdRRTJJmCm@zQMIcGs@DS6LakBpty@fY5ulmIDHrSmL4Kw07GKExaYWAIxkMHZfLEnZVVq0S9jKun6rTSq660lw8z75bpy3P9iecV@gDlU/MmkHh9xcOmjGGT0G@CiMMlczpmI6rK3D7AYUWRPmp1@jtyWxXo2dxCRuLDJxl7rtRynmfilHhwt1p9HAxFd8jSes3Fd9sRyLNBC@3YvyX3wf0cK4P48NTeLb8nly5BOchDJ7adbk5BZssWm7U1F9VYhr//bel5YRwNCxdBv@D3b0ipvpg4S8rvS2C/VTUeXeZ@wEHhSn33k5YmfC6bDyESm1BPobZ837/NIA9pzvAi6mYd8UnHhxZLDrwP87nxrn/TIa1fPLYMwuiO/05osVDMjwejkFN0Rey7Tv0a/Br7Uy3yLSK9YtDorDGcOE8G9wvk60TOSuZKoiCV4Fk5mwBxipIscN0vrov@A6L6POnpmRPl/Vb7GkiA936V5RR1F3PyvROZroevNZACl1fosSteJgZ8dhRVsHYSTfidmo/3Eh7kCx9xBd/rdYrDB4KR0g3DAZgcR0FRfo0IIIR/1mhuV@v1vA6KJCfWccpdzjHjiiA7rOOQDPYYL06rw12gdMozNBawpb71GDjLX6YRqtVkwlC4BTmFVvBHKC3Ilfhtphk2f1ayM0n4upN@i0DLovbqMSA9CrSLi2USxXKmmMmcIMWzR6nRarfhCGLf74WE8Zbf7RLSQotnMTnwCIqY@t/Y@qNT1HlmkZf03Ex6LpWel3RBKs6Vb18P40yryUzu0vc4371y42zeTF3rihpdO2DvUvlwmMC7/FDeKE@LtCDOvGG7UrjSJqylEnKJlJ/n9L6kPE@VsQxu008lXfP3iu55i2Uq74d0/fh1dAf57INBX1mc4tJ8P@j@KOZHm8ISVsGtkhRHfzPbyaDUBhEtTnIkJoiJedhurMdQ3pSMxOEx426sfXDz2iT1Y2YaDYnpNzOw5oyRBJW4zjdMuDueSageTn6eAMEwwWjKjNwNU3iiC08SYJHruanWMZ5C0wOcmjY9xNdxrPtX/DGDPY2cybc0P/GZYH4njZebFmkCsdB97s4nU1qajIZjXz7qRj0wi8R1T6YhzhcSByFWoO1rSApbpy/3QS7Dcb/z3MqJpKAwkmKG7jZFUzrOUDLsu6gLkXjv/FZ47ey2eqQVdv07VYFO3WJ//E7qss3Ij0YRjQGfGjhU0Xgw6Abar5u65escOhjQyntcRoghJpSGvFPDBVHJ7@FJX46hQnl1CMi3uGcYJ0TjK0RLhyUYgb9JtF4GBHKUdyr9CXsmZjdoK3LlxVdj@HGFAO7Ssi@BhPScjB62PEBLyzvmYpE09VLGd39EKhA1PGSfh3C1uuo4fx0H7W9bu2qlWPxTqfi2lCCZMVUX82/fqVpCRTIJK8VSsfi@9M5xtsLBRK42ZtpZwHqXA0BP7WGi/0S86d8gMLdToRmDM0ak@kf@8Mbv5B2n7nfYBnwxZoqAlccgV9/4ecUX0q3g757U3V7kKVp2XUO84Bfzs/iubbNjDc/BHaKBP@wFI7lpFN4EHRDQ3Ju6DLvd8JYN0biyJPRAoZ4/IqK8zqo0SuyXVuPCugu7iyVqILIDO/C7CG/Yj7QmA@mpAdzv8wUgB04UASFZWb8zhQnV1@62gh7YaQ4C8LIUU8AgQE3rjNv@gzg4jMTvxEHphnXC9hieeVumZwok/UIeKzTc/WFA0jcmMPcKF0vgTh3c/FhrqMbhTvNzpV5V9HxUP/xU265uq80T1fxYVVuHRyccAEx9PNwj6dJQlYNt@nrQrNc2j5uH9MGtNKikywlO5eBEVX86qlcbDXVYV7X9o70aQSPw9cpBs1ZteKp2sLV3TJP1rqcIgjo4bKq92n6tSdmahx7Xaoo5cTl1uKP2q/Wtj/Ra2azt1ZonXONOrXmAynaotoo6qtSbta3jvUpdHR3Xjw4bVYWGOdu1xtZepbZf3c5T/VSnqn6qHjRV42Nlb2@qoYefD6p1IJ9q5WaVsKxs7lW5Jm7ndq1e3WqiQfHTFhGPENzzVOOoulXDQ/WnKjWnUj/xNNBG9a/HlIkS1XZlv7JLjXMyj1CF@mXruF7dB9JEicbxZqNZax43q2r38HCbad2o1j/VtqqNsnL2DhtMsONG1VMI5MpVEwyiFqXT8@Zxo8Z0qx00ac44PmrWDg@y1MmfiTCEZYWKbjOBDw@ktUSkw/oJoIIO3AGe@vyxSt/roClTqwIqNIhqW81kNqqQiNhMNlMdVHf3arvVg60qkg8B5nOtUc1Sh9UayEAwUe/nClV6zK1GPxFe8kjM6hjO9bg7VW1HVbY/1YC5zk0c0KhpbmGybX3UNKexXHDmbrk9uIE3u8unTSEPO4nfOtyuksYnkWHc@PsxTTo/pDfvUmk00dhEetW7oDxXnXf8i/HVedC/DLE0t8VkB7sXXXmIpZRF8N0vzgMRwvVGORdYWjo//1Q5p3Vu4/w86z2lZAqNx0poL6wP5crqNnbDVoeX@SnbUpJQG6@0r3dPHC8nbS2vrPEhqwqFjq@L4fIiABszkQ5KQMA6kIx8q7HVV4kqeYs5bSviiBnTxiKzvRlG9Kf/a/wic0PiAwlnObdQKGANy2gg8omy@FMlHBRERwbhcwDBJVeZj3z/21WmmKwOS35toMqaMpx3RMvAq0z2keIX/tVU8dx0eUYWd01ZWTHu4I2bdjBmyG@aZEr3S37ILcuIaY9/sgYbroiUwqxUxRdZ9emTzCspDv@iYivMlq0rcQ4Hsl/5qfYZi7niyrvy1PeP9ruMLdw6R2wbmu9OudwZ/3w8kww0wAIsv4gkwUS2VAuFRBnSyliftJnhq/4amW6DDs2pmKqvfZ7W4SFf3AUny9NkPAzuktiTGN6tV/Y3j3d2SHIC23c/vP/Tf5Qd7XF/OPrJk98T1IMomUxd0qJvA1LTOCkxSrZI79mZCZaTiO6D3kNGRJk0ncYfW6TSWs@ZoiNIfA0xA6G5ESIM9BFkw0WQgKGrcD/ff@4Yfp07MjUDZFJNzaI1vdYda/gtUpWYB9riJbM74V67wx/AtsPfDHHbIM1AmsX83mA0Ic6lxQXLPXfHOBzgtQ1fK0aWvGv4eNAyZ5CEMJCZ7IUBd/D5TfN2ohdJr0VHY7xyt3NJQuL5NBYmSAuHXKIqjsLIjGD5GNCXnzS/0eOJDg6EJIR6qIwaRMYdWzJngveIzVkPDA35bGOduujVK1vTmoIhNauREvt/OnRMcjQwKnKgQU0BNiePLJ1tChuhPyxn1XfhVHj1Bpyy5lj9Tpw7rzkaStm4RNfvJoKMElhxQBn@dGvrcEyWE5PFkjNFpn@JHgz/30iTOfDXaMFJ0GNqsRwO@mP/iZRkqEIrWr0yUYJbc2IscUwtpmby00kM5j7ZMde2YfoY3p1sLBEJdO9MzIcTCSmWmUMAMDnsGsnxCwe@PIivW7Ry@sBj95ns9A/77d4gYwJymaliBu6ZxzqXZ47I4SUrW/hFlahuD/FVPrCfR5YZWHCRFLuYqJeRKzDelFjmoNGF12z0sKOcWRNkKJkRHrNTUQ8tM/jv9AmjeJbpmNR7UkUXB/uy2yGIKZQS@GYHxAgQPvuUbLAmG9W5AUTnthueXtjKr/QsjgiXJAJ5XlZNds8RtS55zYypSPvSgNMOVAk4Lzs6ZtOFP7rFdNEV6OxDJIamMi/ZjQkq0bZIq0YY4ZvNE9V5kr212LOZEvxqsT/uf@sjwLIvJi6TI5@KAJV0wZpX@y0OBtV9WrvduPI3IOtGuv5an/2qtGW/EqY5XrlTLVjpv4xiipDGeQvtkuahmEqt9jd8dA2PBre54I5@uK6cbrmJaURrBo5YN0/pv1@4IACvTJ2BVe6XvjUircpEtv7SqC94krFrn07wpO3M69QoQo6@4MCsVoOAMvQmHNKcHW2MX8qtDg6frpLmdHubv2iNe63@ZasXdCd86vSX8LpfiPrjaJAfTBzXddPWQDgCh4sUwn3kq89BvxPeRmqThgMMSY2D48ZR2vCXsHxtieVLqT9THWqTa3ZmwF/CZ1IUXo6oa/yymuho5cPY3MN2Qm1pYbPWBB/gmGrIDET19qxmvHtwrHb9vj8kffCIz1yqvaDt90l8kDLFpzCja5E0yL6D2hu6drUD3YUtO2XlB2zUsbY9R1egoXlgrQwNRUJ4qMMqwjY/IVZP2ATzsw2O29UxRqXrcKC9AcFoCmVTTJyX467nIHbj51rzIxbjsjBn2wxNa8bWB1uiqE49MdZSY4at/mhCRHGmjTeE9mO2m7xiZ0AE0VlMTl7U9RCgvQOzXzeipiLUvJYCPIPQUPWDGwSLYzPcU/qIz9lqs1lMt7L2r@hJ@DojOlK958S95yFmaN5T7/9TNX3wrjrqttq0wlKNMYq/fUt64GYYjZB1v6JUcaVUKuVKb2GiPW5U8jwQ8L@JIOY4tf2jw3qTCKld5BvGsHMmiM9Bu@Q0FpEjh9Bd1PqvEMgmP0nMla9MPKjgxo@vW5YdC3fVpb5vt2DupRZGaXWYTbIwyYdDDhwGb1DEQqnhSLXC6QFC9LGQRE0J6B6HLtPBx2RqsXiyNz8u8BW4dYmvutgP/cqF@RsJAP@Ov1GpIa8MOtrtPfVJz@9Z7IORmd1bksGZjnlmCSa2VGKOZW8ZWhJRL5uE0/FxRiJC9IBedNMekmxp3RDL4QiLcYlFPMOyKWtb07oIugGNAcKrfR1iwhFxZTqCTRDJiGgO97iNtYMJiXGZE62ARlcn7NmsgpXjWGdw@vsgmrRDtXRFy2ystKKB73c4UsJ4IKEAkJ6nUd6lmUPcxK3GMQKcpSKfmxySsEFIFpJ94y58x8LX34X0uWNaQ1xl3As2r7GsF0DUosaIBykitmXmrLA9hX3eLHd7ixgCZbMgxAJHfwRi4GFTirCi/maG4CdmFw/uqLrc39N@AFGQgxFFg3QCYMmurp9OMODRdv04k0GYdN0iMOVi0CAjfrLkOWUDS7@gvTh3CqdpGWkjNW6StcTcCRBCU2wDoboK8ReZ84Ziskfo8x7hjOPCO7jkJXjTOUuzOSmXDSCSyLkyB2ZuLsy382HmNEy9WVnr37DDNpRitpBWiDfokOQjCBE3fzc0opfdynVD2WCyrb/qhheI20SSgmrDz8SLOzb5mVdgKUInU8WJYDre1JppkkZd320yuotao/Hhb6g1Y7HY@NKXjtIJ6zKW2GeZ4rmLhxM/4o8eUfzopoJXQeuYil4F9OQryW6AdTVI/cVdVfHIxEmcZH5dc7pIL1WkNFVEI5cucpEqsuLEnkqnehclIPrxm26Z0Uv4VBL3gFq3HVR0eq07Wd0U2QEdm2kQMjLlEW/lTDMIMp62lfVph@xnTuyiObVtL3WYVz6Cxye@3Rcuh7wqpuMd3JmjeywGOFcqfcJuwPsZ3aCsJgO/WPfPWYOMbtcaF@knJJVtsCQ4qWYPcVcrk6wlu6qWBi3ZNUSuCBNbsupTpgF26V3691pldAW5JLKSCW51tSgkwrPr5VNaykq3GDlYdOKZmd8SAo560BH5zUfGZBrIZFLjykhuC1MeZ2Q3gcJ3Acc1OeL/MyK9Tr5iRkmIhgYUPoQx1Uqef0fLM95jZhA8/1iLtf4oPo2t9NDIn8Y1n5lZI92Khbmnp5J5eRKziqXCQ5kNsS2dFmZePNsw6WBDgLyT7AnS7cFIrElnpuDlSEjGWkowYmenYTsQCZUmW0LoSllvjgBOd7lBzptqlZNwZa5bOD2NOKmZM8UkmcQbwrSrlxLITgBlnVQp0H9Rh@O4Y3JgL8xXkny62xdxhIVl@v0htrCZTb8/xBaSOdHtD7OFiWVoScvlp/ki1RNCAhxK1CsGtiklZZBJuEvmupvKxQhNzpK@zP1uZg62CamqbZ3OjKpkSaRDl6Tr4J876Zgl7Wg0xY5EvFPbG2dxa2mOa3/zO9Yjs269XSJtuOkpQXpzOhABGm1q4D46yyJkti1AEluMYHrN3JOzm@zRflkWLLwGRdSuq@v07d4UWDOrFLOzCqXx3h8jvzYX@dxsFIV4ibU6Gx/eni7TWOPAUzjsILfrzNnxdR7B6k0Cq3TrEj2UJvECSLknQco9AVIhAUkP7Lc0X/Lj0hBx6vzHQHz5MguDf36mhZSGQZK2E8CIjXXwbWvyGMznpGwt8Zm6lpwqswViPfkxGD9Ow@C4oNd2N05/vG7B6vZ3fxhOR@VYSNk0r8zByGK1NIuWB7RYavN6V@czqhKvbfPfLq4DuxJYerynxY@xLoyjxNd2E2gp7VXfAovHf2kB/bxEt6bHgyCeMsOQtuz8zuGQByHEwiRXxWyBhCBLr0N1QpoQD6dOCz9erU57P0bA04XFso@25IMYfBJGpxI1TSRWiuPMEi4WTma2MvJt3vLs0fqX5tY/CAek41zORYDz92DHF6PUlEiPVdOppfWT5rK589lsu5J621RskqcP8lczTV@hpuNiOg3qvn@rZ/@HIOu2mB74A5r8qeGRBUi@nIskNtpb2ril@uPehT90njLUpUQeP7JGWsy5jrO0pCptWjJrz/iwirU5fJ@vq4QaDEaI1HiA/ZpIDndicMNG5gsDT@fthLd9zp13UQXbaHt@q69d5esJ82qI/Qub10P4Tlzu4hqCfpsIHfkJ8@dXiUnd8XUKTiQ/QNby/L4HV6NOjYUX16TREl0zM0mvaeXrAgXHajWca3VaUTG8g83Q16KZa32JFPPsfBPYU7SnhxQiYuJFVeoF7xToh3l0dTExxwNLSts1TyDlPHXLWrmfoG5Nnqpu/RsoOd2hTuJZaw96gl19VKhNL/Kd3woFG5ixN8d1y6fmzk7K4cnFxKwKev7wfbFYhBOci1bEuxYpbzjYJQ7CQjp3ATbxwuD2z8NPFwUUxaYFIhOsms1MPwq7JGqifDi8kmgUwIGyIje2JsAn2JoY03yTCPcAe04ft3J@iSSneODpKD7GGdjD7Z@azHwMEsTzV9VXNBDt@6oux30xot@2ZMmgoZjzZlQaauiNa47JEXnw4RIedeyRNAbG62Z9awEbH@sb351nvAcu1wU5XHz2e3wN0f3od7uhpz6Hw27nuSu3Q9MFdnaSBYqSBUcJZfBEHL7YU/5N0E2EcEYW4BZ2/Xw3vGJw2AHX1xb5LtPQH2AnLYN5rO5fVe8GGff0Z5cYk5r8Bs18o9wzXO@5cmmKcnkL/XGwEjCD0H5S7l5rkGkznaYz0xyo71LFT4TR25KnGnI6GPaULWoyDnNkUlmy4hdGaPZ4bhB1Prr5X8Kgn6GmI9nBdTm@@s3dyy1ZkN0S1/1yV7oEDYsCQ@OEED1PK3FfhtOpP/4frNuwHOByI9t47ZXYhL@xZDuMMR4jS92MLi9peIklfsO4GjPgWFTmSnxKAaTRHTv0/4ZYBZnly2hZAqzgqE1j0m@nEDldOfPU8nh0@cMyQfiX2uiYEaiHH9ETxyb@kqNhvTPmON6xPGMzHA5QzModFDhHAcd52V7/222mUqmoF4M3b1SlskkPuZyqbFbUNj5sbqptet/E@6v1lffvy3Jybjv7nT5umo/3apNg8BT0hhYC2/RKaetYUWEphS5@UVh/4ZVfnK@vbZSjwmll86xQuKKnf/7jv//5X/9TqOiX/8XLJr@c/mwz5fP5wov29xev7st4P90@W35xcfpicLZ8VQaX/R8)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
140 [Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
142 [BitChanger](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
149 [CSL](https://github.com/jammy-dodgers/CSL)</sup>

### Explanation

K-on Fuck is a brainfuck substitution based on the character Azusa Nanako from K-on. The commands are made up of combinations of the sounds うん(un) and たん(tan).

This perl script (with -p flag) will convert brainfuck to K-on Fuck

```
s/>/うんうんうん/g;
s/</うんうんたん/g;
s/\+/うんたんうん/g;
s/-/うんたんたん/g;
s/\[/たんたんうん/g;
s/]/たんたんたん/g;
s/\./たんうんうん/g;
s/,/たんうんたん/g;
```

The brainfuck code that I converted is

```
-[>+<-----]>--.++++.-----.
```

which gives this K-on Fuck code

```
うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
```

This is the wrapping constant for 49 from the [brainfuck constants](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#49) page on the Esoteric Wiki plus some code for printing and adjusting the values.

This code is just after the Aheui in the polyglot.

Answer (score 8):

## 154. [c*ckf*ck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck), 6985 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(3 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S / \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz (  coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# do            x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRc -BkBkBkLzMbMbMbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8=,
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n114O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p seLzLz
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                  @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclxx"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _ @125iRE
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''         $>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/pppppppeeeeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*<s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001912

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1bc/PKdhj4vJH5B37pj9LeJMULAN4pifo@XkVSFEnxKuqytUEQIEGCAASAV23tsmemTnxJzSQnjuvETnzOcTI1rpo8uDIzVUnZVVM1eU35R2w/uqbm/IMzqxvgTaL0fdvOQCLQ6F69evXq1atXX9HljMFvf3uAL1RV5UVfVk1kCoaJero0FXQ/Si3QJ04ywoEgRWGopN6fjAXFNI6pA8QiJCm81IN3ZKojQZGWgg7@AYQ0Xe3r3BiZA85EgsFzmmAgdWJqExOp4v5oQYSyY3Uo@XDMsaT0AcwUdE0XTBIeQqipyNy42@NehIRfJKjpEG6gjCB/P/7eRLw6HnNKzwDICEKZSipbSr7AEEXoUtUNAePhBcNQsWcMoXlW4F@AxgGU0yW1lCyfvwhiGXQOpHOaLMwR1zVMneNNSVVwEIvq5Wa9@jJGALUaudxL3yC68KkKyk340U4QKYOqrvYmPOaPORAgGPNUlGTBoHjI@xnS7JL0Ywc6QLrA9SwwSlR1hKOg8UhGEuI1DXVlbuDnkSwBbI6JIQEXAVpCuDww0FwbAwZDHQvbdBhIEYQeMjSBl0SJJ6kjYW4KigG5NfxIArpnkiyjniBDhA1JvBeQoYmx5WUR4Kd6KoXg4rUXGVi/HQoAowgrJggalAJmgooLDTiy4sVM5zQNiARG1oFwUxqD7Emm00ACZ0hYuiGKISg9wj9tLfcq4pTtXKKpxCEO6J3oBLch6Lgw/QQvGgi6ACi5teS5ZrpkAgswe5OoKnA6auiC4N6tAztJQmIqTsHEGfGT4js9dWYrOScUoxXDz2kmdaAHG1dFikP@BDp8OIFfwuE4obLlDHo6vMNuS@ShqDXdxblR4gdk0Hd3AvzmbJfu688UYKWAKzKiVc2kOZ8GBPpMIJDmsBO7fNOAX5O3EkanL8piS7gsqB6UBiooqOUlOeMnuo6r9Yap3AgyLatKH/gJmdUnCuaHgiIMFAGvQq30ImEKXANxJ2WkzgiHGwMJCs3ARbJVkSzlRBgK6glkz@boKl1DlScEDmIaJhZA4ApExRgLImohkZNkHAXCMSqLal0wJrKJ40yUHi55UD5Cz49WZPBqDwON1SkkxwFS4gF1abxVAwlRAAwFoZKs4qAf//mf9fp9wJPkeVXv2eLaQj2VJ2qUI8SCbkJYYFWFkwlZAOfFqVvRIYEpJ0s9zsTJKws7CUIESXWmTuQeUiFBfSZB1RpwU6iOoijwpmAJuaV5vWjMjSy9IVmSCxkfc10oWJIASZtk24c@paGUeIE6IDLjG09MMYZ8WhY5Dfpb18dj18cPdwIQ5/a7jw5pun8CAuc/Il7w5nxPclrJHc1omJyhSj1KW5gDVQkgH48cfELVBMXl3MHh9Dr1rtPtx/rM5T6RErxflJSeywkynoJ0ne4TPsHfSsf3Jy9ib6cIWGYYC66tgot3OyjQOKROTOkxJyl@bYFaPtu1FaYaD5jjONi/5Y358tJvankckIYHi6WK5QPUkN@QBUFzMX7WjbUEhtubbRywL6MvcNgZPpbuPc4Dp2c76wQD5HQno7iuNiQVay1ZG@C2BZiiGBpobx2LLs@B8BhYiZvQ@ntRl4g10fygWIhKnAlOXUBd0KMrMSI10qpxOL4P60kbw6YGreB2K7TQ26rPoAugSpvGK6UsqzNImNCGmy/QIApOnOtDEUFkK0NJK0NWisRnN2sjBfQKxtYVUMzXlaAu4FoHqt0W/a08AngwYMEANquubKmgMbcALLzVJG7qDZJEqFJj0BL6AvECVj2ggwSrXcGJTEg1NMDuwRYQ4wuEw7tV7VVNM3U66bsBXb2k361QOPPbdQrrGyQKMyRzSn/C9bHppUAUjucFzbT1FeTEMEEjvWx2iKfPbkP9xoA6/PQybdKW2K3rVhpY11ulZ7eIHFYytvHlk0GnIs42H1FP0kE7yYuXqQPA9EXiju8wyA4B3zneIGFlCICQCXOBn5ig3ECQZwOJH4DsYuoUSz1abdHL5MFrO3VQ8D5xnTQmhj37JkD56bUXJuNNFD5coq/xQBuLUZ3teJDC3/Z4HzNnjPcgVtckQnuw5eunOT/I3mdwjlVF3YMUGLlGi0F2Q6xyAIOsjo1BaL9W1heprGsLcV1EUGagPaDmg/wNTFMzjqG5kMzBpOsHSaEb@qJgVhQsLLSpLyRTtdxdWe2CejagftKrFGh@0pXmLzJE/NZlODSoKdhhooES0IA/TkDqXE7RAMVJ/NMYeCvIQRQ4QWHdHQBIgPzAKJdoEJWcA6VSXyi8y@EnVckPlc7hRQ5ccR1ucOBYa76k1THWQqhN7ANs8KV00FwiaCtb9xPVz@1t8dZtADHvnE7/UJUU15Pzw4cPzmPnGWj4Dx8@gusUuz5ilwdcH4nLR1wYzo9dJIaXuHDoLYmB/e6dz7crzHP3PS62OW6dlpLm4m6Pj4P3Xu6WtZ8B/HSDqgPNBtA@/AA8TncigZ1ut@NsBhn1d8Xd3Kexdq7zuqTZTChyU856t7kQJGyQxpqqYzv2BDe27/NknNChNQTblR@4dOfdLXN3f/d01/PcPTu9OLb7hEt0IVOQnmvs7@vqBJpN923o2Mfeu923QWgsuwkn4zxyuWI@GRLi3O6vY24PZ3Hb5RRAa7vu7pzAVJs/t/xAJ/jm3oDbvWYV0IEbaDANXU7/UwzS77rv3R4nxHU7vdDTSDidwBkeM8EgmcaSSRiUAwFM10s7vbzxCNQj4g0Z2xQ@3TIr4JU@sjx75LG2nI5RgbSsCrSXQAI0l711D0dRFZ8yIXYwMVLV7YRIXwxDED/ceGDFKO3AYMSiNAdDHyruYmXR4AYYGzVp6O2psuBvExvDgUDyEa6v/r1mTdVqF/y8sSlEMGDAqckcDzVzF92dA90BQhBUmt4f4j55hfilzUN6J5/LI7QMPKdg/vUkYn1PJGOA2QsmEu4S6CJwFZve0LgLhGsFxEOj3QdOC3PJtGxxEIQ6jpLnDJcbm39Jy3zCVhtu8jFRq147aY9VHvotAjT9ONTqBKKsMpV0VcFM9mcBNUjsCS6DF8j3sRfEKJksBDJv83cfcuDYK292i7fbWF8ylzd4RCuqrPZVdAQAWDT9fluwoXI0BhOBEviBihx30IQEzhDdE6Y0FkgH6OoB2EI@sDcEnbS2JFrNUsU90nzUBKVPCXOiEsqVTPahmmzkEw56Yui0LHUh6Z7wMIYmXxYMx574y5G8ig7OmqqaCVKXsP@aSHuUiDLVCRgJPUGWxpJZIMMlsoJbwo2WX4WmId0NgqokmJRtvm4aRzxyslFckA8CX9geRBF1dbw2iQybUYdBzBphZyAM9xPs0BAOndjDYFv@Uew/xkNYfp7q8zzyqdbr2tMGjGFAPKzl5zWN6ns8GJIMc609bcg4QYmHuvx6d@X5xDLP2H89zrVleG5j3Bf@dqQ1cpYgN5SJoW1l7okNEP@pKYpYc669g8R75AM0ml2ke4b3bPAIhu2pXUGeR0I@QRb95nzpx9ZIJERZD@TrvQWxJy41X@6LQJlgWvjm4osATqcsChtQ/0sq1PWSZJDR0G2hoNaNyh3lWLWMOw2gYxMS2PRU93evHdtYiOiDOI1UbI1tXA/QlwzvoBiP5NcxRdCJ5LYD@oqi1yEktjHuiuS2B@DY7rJBBcLjh5glRTz6hHuNKrRQwoyAEeOTIANWSQpH18gDm6H76Nk1qHeI6QriBJQ3DdYBdn8GzBePEUix25XeAgW@YNJXzz1g@qS7j20gXINXfS60w3hzopuy0LOf//V3e1AAr4tnwC1Ig7V2PADfcFH5xDdLy46KX8htf8kSmOFEljjCBuL6HEqew6NdnLx27EeNFTjy@QacDoW7WBUuCCe@QU1/R84synVBnvSE1XN/IoTFuz07K7YijUmO4IkNG2KovhH9Rb/Uik9MA1nlegSL1YBLwqa0rXIR5lwfMkdvaSTQp19A56r7iDbDttBPMifWHY/Ufq5cJQ3/9nPleFfImDDXZQVaNbiu9AYfMRmRtyTbqjC4Z@MTZW5kOR@wc39mrezoUr8PPTr7@RYYdN9NwdDAhKFn5PGOWKyaDkTMAu49nLps3d8CWU1SrR1vAUJWZXL7KcJHxIGHGoJlB8@X@LbYJL1grMx1F7hPMvjpUoQTJG0yKJkE7/EwQdw8rwfYNjMzmvZ2fGxPkPjx@P7Y1iQOQcCroigIn6u50PpIY072BXpbzjcV8arHvHHtAR1ClxIMYpkzQEhMm83CFIqF3N4TXNyg8FhcNq53xHZDzmoc9a2huE0cTeJVWTI0Utyrl7c04stBjA0aPE1Hbpuo@O01f3tg/uPG2rd27a/UKm/i4bA35OgLlJQ1EoXH@rYEw6@@xTteneHfm2bCQJ0K1n1/w7XcS9UXqCCfTCRD4vdE7/GfE1c8r0Ju@7k42kuVyct7/Y/RparqA0ExUMDPrLrueDQbuu/W0FijUHlbpg1JVg1UJ/f3eAHdB8Ow7vuleZttEqf4yADFtnt/tL1EkUYOJcn9jcLl5L4qR2J9moPbmxIw0UWs6e3nl2q4tYZi2c9qqLXRoyqs/XxTtY/g/3PCQQZFdDz6ueV8x5bap87sUbO3Mwj9AjylsT9zOSZGYvppq8/3VgHo/GDGLVbPf0Dr8RZ3V62HtiAmM9h0OEI8Bg5Tt8zof0hqofdT632ZjnqFNvq5TGwV7kgWQGOT@6siRQGG/YkxWIb5co0lyhNhIuzVIJXuUMCLQ97RHV9OFGNn49AeJaGBeXgFyBpqaXcIv4hq3J7jt3cVDidLUMk/a83sVTUa2Nka7kBXwVHFjtcR@8pE2yncLd7VJkrtfc4NtFXNVns7ROKQn6qRYp@3mXZMcUMgv7fM9uxYhW6vOgYbQvmC8reRkgEl676DmPhsMA8lPLalv4v3GK2nScB@BXsESlUaGT48QPZliifwVn@dAMfj0CNTBHOB729xe58i7aqq/FNKB/RpT8JmGhifeCnU50rple1jz5ihzciEgUc5uuJbYxJWW2N3HoF7uKP8ZkFXIUsmaRy@pJRfjRi@02ptjR9@rg8JLTYZ@DF0fuV@i94artysP@aPvkvwalSMXjneQxb3B7/EPtJWRi8ZnsVDutYg7maI/@CF/tEWwCmp5zP4gTAWyOs7Fj/XG06M1eNNoLmKf3uC/TQZYH0jniZBhVfwfWfAeMskMlVFMGiT0/sC7qvIAgfWqOX7lpJdjdvuZW5hzPWF3GclazPsgNdSkHmrLef@AYhja3qTh2ifUSNWN1BVRsLCWD33G8sLHspzMn4X275KzuPRzc/Waj@9d6z6MzafMlAHykAY6KRmrN/eqhsgkaa1LPS9TAD9A84Y4cUjRCFt@ngDY5u7sirLX8JdrBAt9aiq@wdes3jRZg@i/iS8C64LAfbjs2N00G4TJpEG/K26MxAm0DwZqqlqgo@8vQUq4xEe675/LLlQcRqoLQl6z5o4w0N7nCl1ZQHNJCBhaGzPDuwfPerKKofXJ71jwQNnVs8vGY/iVf1zTUKfU01NI48HTZ4Y5EaGcH3i/rHJY5QjhH6JLEimNWVpSazQV7v8QPpc4XUFzlSkEW3Xfvt1v5Tv6mKScQn5MtjbL0vAKn3hxzKQ2A6v40dhf72XSvZi73eNkfRE1xef1w27k43r4VRrEgA73hqMsSed9gSTZh/Py6/mn9@ZibDnqN4UKGJIY6PZJzBgmbBvDg3trCGwWSAHg@ZnuMSr/OhztoQ9g0qW6K5XcRlee20x@Em6vZLUWC/XPigovC6QNV2rNT7oAK80m4wnMmequh8ROJeL83jcbsqKhAdi@gqAraDIglm8is5ai2sgWTJMAiuJ6PYWHT7Nj5lj9hklkOPYge7vLaxkPVd2rpGVrjUr6u0hd584dPp8zkPnnXKMGCcBFWToF@8F5XbgRIk8LDo3WUcKZ83iY/cqpyfW6kBjQBbgQu3qQS1tgmFHSkrVrTVu1kLKBp69@S9/2bPXJUNLbqCxZEA/qK/gtfTqWBios49WunbqSU3j8LpmjGM2wCoAp@5LJ5Exw9XZWo6szlAz14jZqxvt1f7wUsVyt0WFVajYpsRLG0yr0CxqeqpgiYWd8DrWKlO8Kk/GCujPnjkw/KgukVULE30zfQ0uDKaYOm5Eel5UQD0Bj5uTxSjEbpJVdUTm5TEl/@UvrTWdZEkKiBB2r5InS7q3UsQrT1iykJLn1QlQvUKyFHTVBnFhJkPbPcFdEhBqwfJ344UaZLEpSKJvtdQSJ2Mtt0wn68iXRU68JQEv4DqRRNdhsnbeumXuEz@gMS3819@l3U823xxf@6IRw@FFK5CTZyxX28FhCN6EOpHjcO6ws4UXv5O13muhsnfEuLCbFNdq6eSYrJsncifMyNJJssBAwaYJXpCuGFA/4NVNUFuVJnHomlj2r69uojDetwEmJQcua6U9WYiClwHiKIdz9D0aYFnx8YgNM/BmMUTGK0/HidRq7jO4PT1NZ4TuhEzVTAP@QDBBsnP4kDg9Iy5d6Kl4Ifjtt3fzAOO7m0ez97SxYs7d3fxrJnAN3FOhaT78hsYVKFvOPB36z5jvvze4BXI4np0n1nQ91PLDp2qhmq03ko1mHbj5bGX2IKfqY26jKbAskPUtA1UmK@yBLbokGJ/XHmsNsn4DcJcLHXLoFO/lcbvXAWtQm9UOn@PQcq5BwEbdjv2Z6PviG8JW@GsAWzOJErK1KKoSQbJlxmlsa1DvSrZwueDqDpbEmiN47cQeVUh45EAJ4JIPuPSFPEKvc2mV4EfiAcX4eUa9j2MfCuDVBuI1AGbSOi2cXyvcytzezD//N8ixBu3aPzbHBMe7OcYQ7@UYADfRSIxcslBq1rK7kUCcNtupoB@g4111Iqlb1sYMS7pUexPASjMRE9qwF/uudauBppJBTGwsbyJuGaCXSqojmbE1sHaxlgaipGyAJu/1QDV1FybWbKDS/WSVjrVUx6cgxwEwy79uaL3IQWFYI/F6MThorhkPWuw7K/IhgSOYDWrP5pU7gf7xn/@ZtWHlzgT3H9juOZOCtz@y30Rw/7NVCMvC279YvwXg7efW27c0ZuXr5flWbtZMxAxsFarIIL0AzKIxN9/KPW7bcNspKWCHSmPg9ZSwDoNb2dpwZoPHddsCzkNxAduxksZ6maQn6PcuvLj6mKaxKYLHbfxkTYgwt/oAZK314wRvNYKmhI6EIyEWjGDBN10hJOsl@3gRgoXQ7T4GqaSmkpb4rsuj09NT5DB4ThYSkROL5fQh923Q8d2a0EOApSyr5RZBHIiyiQFhZ3Y01yHnYd04Kq6cTtaJ7k/AILFKENo0F3EAiBt7K6sFhdBoqjarQDwUYW4Sxb9YWWNgCilkCZxgbThbIfIBIgs33hHzUso3Sw3wEqwtufdvF4OjjcHqGOzYsU/Ibr9Fd@adcm9vjEIgML/aI3IKuP9wz26ptfQkX@/Tcb3cZYNzgz7VFRUvP8kBtcgVoANBmo24t@qUw0YF9OIa9D2ghDoDdZAXpKGqGcl0tlCsVOuv9pkQSOdLMCdynp167nx@7@392uF8IfUrpqZydP0ylVuxcpuqzQguhtgM474kc19qLyl9I/W2tcbjddok4FVCLPOliMmQiS9HZjpeY9@E0luAaWsO@lWqLvfT8@396dmdcvAq@e/3bcE78B9h4QLXnUE24DnRHp1TWK1caeB91oZ/tRQy4NhsMF0vF7XeN95v7xRZ79rebBdZrZGhyDrf9TJfyv/G6hnIu5@2kiJ7JSzCVvSCrlmRymJSNwny1KtR@G1qkJ2X1xvM7RWwayZVrI4s2QrHKdCH0SXegjaIgra6u2TfFnR4CuamjwT9LtyPJl3BBen2gKpYz@j3JDJ@yOmr1avrkLowlnyNFT1YcWy2f9j7HgaQN1nqnnCJ2zlarwR9bxeE39BkyXThLRlzP@5OQm5cbpwB9hTvaZi7T@P39vYRtNrl4SEbRaoT4FdV1dCmC58RVq4a9OJQZgLIQQwEVJyMAU4kj5qAWwkBlVUfRAY@OldE3OKtEXYe/ONeGFL3D4R5T@pDS@Nye0Elfc2ymy0mHN4joThBD1usOsdLFbYZ85O2xWxxjLvl/JLSE@YuvGL9@B5zB/yds/bU6Xa8kgGyN8feqtJ7uUlnpSw40661mw0uLxRCPL5WBLt1Jx73DwwKr9SFHgikWDf1EjihDXWJY05DrgnZ5WQgPyKvrjuX4jVM3Y18Z7g9myEFeTyk7wIPEuBHJKZIXJKMhwBdeG@wi05AOWNfQ@nhx1LS0C3r99@DmyTiRod49CEN5gbut7spME0hyjFBCw0w/B1jimbQS8MUWc9DkixF9ikA1N5gUpH7A1IBgRck1@jsm82i/60aaHE1Hj@2S2NXHcYRiMXpHo0BaPeouZVtCvy1l1sC17ASA6g0dEolUCifLgRFgfrqApkZQ@1E3ASETHd7VwdceDd7nkkKBxaJeXv9JhC6uxc663ySVbBnDukT0gM@eYZ2/7s73PCLdtO/oH@H9tMnT65DObGgwRhzn7kOBwnWEzzyeA6VI9ehgs2Rb77BHefnQ7B2HvwOv2MOQL5D2X0C8gzWUeJQOTnkTl2HvUTgiMSAV4/H/QQRfjBo/9Mh90wffgPWhBd8dKt2ug4Nsj@J8fvZZ6AP15BD2gsy84T36ZDjKXDyh5LHg2nwHz5gAn6g7@oe0q7c1WnSRz@xjVy6P16pkV1bZV0Sr47bsBhoex@vNXqYrMO3pugeVsDbW6H3hO2zj3772wM2At2tj5GgS/V8DDMnHmeYPXEeoINPDvrIoTue7jK@KRJ8zltODPgf76ujavXafecKojhyHqQrDjbk@BbFA0c0dUAfMd9Hafq7774DQxTdnvnP/PfuW5/z/tZldaWi6CwaPfJGYkfeT86HTd8tityuQMBdRzS6Q2F0F@W4I08o8Ek5gaA4voKIBSe@x@DHonAYZfH1t//H3/7ib/@Y/P2C/P4aSZKkGb0e/NQBGqElXCMR4X/iXva23Bx2d8UlAgLBzAfrL4El8yu42KrTGQ4669/ivYAfP8Af@Ydr/YrvH4iP7U1AXl8fEHVwxh8sD1iWPViQvwfsZudbl2/@/kWzbODuK3zGS@TDp6@Av4KHXMfHnzaMpB3RmENVic8Akggj9QB3BLauuQ9f1MG8weE/1Ojiv5qJ/1oj/Ffj8R/ypUb4r7S87OK/F@TEEl7q4IdEwvPuhfb4@f0PKxd18N3pd4l/xIXzQx1At@jg7Oz@@dnju/V/6zk5sf9BoZys3/BluYCAe4/Pc3p7euo/O5uf@e7PbqmDJ2DJM3UQcIDc3x1RB4n5aY1QeZs5W@Vm5yqBz6nv/rZaAou@4Q2c@g4CuWTaG6g3UwcsvIU3rzgwiF9r2WSm0gToaimbrGfPC61sswr@xv3D2adPHj8UzSfgz9k9UDT/2nPmSZimiW4ejvzoC66HPS7rlTrInM2btO8UiC5RBzWSks//cHb/PXVwe3Dr8nz0fGRkZsqwI3Z0qVY2/5XKHAKkOTNUdWbADNgeSC5ihCazYBZzZqxW2B44BfhjxuCUGHHO9BmFUVg2VIlUPu1ge/t/XFEvKyrgUyGuOWdMjJoR4dmvVC4BowipD@FPYhhmDmTOmSn8MzJLrm8fGMiom7m7o26R4zsBtJCfdfoZpz/idEr34Yj2@PQciDzeEnMlHL@/xdsO7x3I63y4uwUV47w/OaCNuzva0tGOQMhxQrYmPj8/PGSSjeTDA40Heuanh55PHt8nuBJnnlP78fGgd3by8e7Yh6XbknD/wwF9@vHuLOjD7ogHGB4Av1Pa8xOvDUp4frijnK5Zu93Gv/ZsOrNcxGH53bXXofjWpsHLcmEvuDAovS/@rmP@WsBcrtvw/dOz2@2@c5447U2@LkR2@TrYu3lARAGHmxj/cWg52SC2zyJh99lZJAzvkZjb52JIsBXlzqFp2p3DTwYT/GSNWiKR1HVuQYBC0HjfOTj94c5xG7hPJOJh4h32xSNI1X3xoNvhdn/Lnp7aaQTc4O1wzh2q7kRPz9t/rqfnUxe53PjP7cae9v3M7YJgdxje5k8udOo6dWE/8MKxnp7PsJPAPYHr1uW@dz8/W35wd7lPLZxnbmAbHjH5b/ivGsjQoKF9PsBGl4JCYberuxDcoYgr5onbf4kPkAGXI@gMQr4cTs55e/vpKHgUDd1@vD/yH@Gf6/Tu7H5Pq@KGph5qzErAE@wBZh914D@pOdiAw4kF/oS3dw7Lah8F4ye4RT6hDiCaA64DkEdoPk/PTtdCsmlr3GdQJZ8Q4Rpy3yP38xMIjhUIRpnLnte4u5szuPYiNzrpJg6fDrjnE4IfPTtW4Lb8Efwu5wmZ@HI8OQ45/Za9dzw7Dp@6z9h6PWLdxEgKh05OjkKWOxoDN3vktsZywco5WbshRDA4/gRX9JMDLB9OYKIbcpXoCn1JAYt1uwJ4wuHwBzoAj/nXkWxgfmRfZ0d7rlgg5jnyfLo9AkMeF8U98f3@A3WCZ5WsKSyHz2FVIxSLEyIOkGHEESi0U@Gw6pmv/o4yR5aLxb/sB4OCjlcXRGSGogw08TLeqKOK4gfLH3qQqCsIYMQLsrzaag79DLk3g079B@oAG1VgwhkCXOMqJ0wEYTaZzIT1lZaMY2445DRy/firn/34q//xx1///Mdf/@zHX//iN7/8xc/g95fw@7n1/Pl/iIfx/Te//Bf/y49//mvw/Gv4/Wf4/aff/PJf/671I@9/A7//a8vvb@zfFpz1owDXH/3ml3/8F7/55T/7U/j9W/v3py9/P/7Jf7T@/2/7Dzt//eOf/A2@2S8/@zn193/1K/z/x3/19//5V/j/f/13f/9X/@rv/@jfE8efWY7/59/@B@v@d7/3s7/77//l3/3eL9@4/@zd@y@/wP@X/z/4fDmdX4LnS/L1U31@@Q@i5x/DjU0qIFC/@MMf//Xvg5z@CXb/U3DDP/L4rMtjA/wB9vz@kGHAzrn7fhvye5oF4wPRW55/gL6/w6u/2Q0k4P8339MMGEmMBbnGuQ35h7/55b/8C/D9/hMCPxvy91fRbX2zA7mmExvwVlp/AMB/vgXzBz/@6nd//Iv/4cdf/dmPv/ojikX4gMkP6AMVQPiJb9iTOIhrfkSFg6DWVm524w6GiDsM9322Jp40/Phpx8vCfbQPmAB@JOEf9pquOI2jFW37Evuwir8Xw0f0CYKhCSKt0Cm@4xfwSUEnwe4rJM5iKEF5USwBvecUBkzAOwnHTvIODRY@tDJBZVYQCGWAH7g1m8@ht/Ed@m7lf2aBojMK/UCgbTQJC9EPFHja8X8gaBM4znxOEWz43zaxsBv/VgGrG3mlbI@5BTx/5UFBhrwkOhVFzSrcaoXzfGPr2cgm03kqglKVcubFI2wDhVEpm2usX6NW6CpqeI2iky2VXr7aj456fJz4gQ1FKXjC2wSfCIJbGHyW1Jyc9ug/PQVRv2Xun0LRQCgcCgeCkUg4GmBDkXgoEo4FGZaJMOFAgI2HQvFYPPqM4hR19uQ7PaXO6tkGoGlUEBtg/NTZNZr7UbV65XumzvC4YMJqRgHVk88wKAq3sR9QOOr1@v1@uOGnl1zk6T/8dgXCvt25OnCwDBt2OCJMIOpwQEPq@@hYCGiAxiiITjTIXWlZWlKXeI4szlqLmySMFly6EMfLOaBxnilkNU0XH2A20d72hAf2wk5d6g9MZM7UNYBhGGC7r636lUW/tuzbqMtx@PdTL0hB2L7M9z1MKw3i9ypEfg1O5cFGGeODQfBSUhMPFEkiYig/Lq1AIB4Lx@LBQMwbi8dCYTYSDnvZgJeNxqJxxgvMj7GRWBhY642F4sEQSIUXyj8cj1IHgtKTRJqGvjoLnXb8lBQe72E/xYcBqP7BGXXQE0S88gfNXT03OuitPSYx5AjG7hgEER1shMKz8EfzBHT68PqEIItYB@XgEI8Ocrk0k8s5HCn8AsqfSTMORw@/hGMME005HAIJSYPwBiDSAL9lIwzeEOSQ8Es6mcthDEP8EohhHA7HyAqxXuTVSxTAFPwSDGIEyOF4XKNjALlqURQjsUzrhWFSaYdjYpEXgz@AS1pvIUJsFr/gABwpZ4WkIczhOF9FgjbN4ahZcHZS@VV@k0mHo2C9JJMYRZFkPmxl6gK/JMkFkXR4A@l1OPrg6OtggDocXXBiGXY4eHDxCw78xuDCC@gVk3M4FlY@cE4cjjmB5viRw/Gw8od0gJ58nhuYPaFvXQvdevIQVIAgaT7J5rrn591@v6svktnzGgkqFvPccDHRu/2uHbH7AJeKY0HQaLx4eQk46OGBk/cHXUCQ8iLoYfEgEAofuEegzL76OKHxQxEHFSFo36CejRCuMQB38ZUawzPFda2g1UWCyHPe7TpOQGgpXH3QwuV@IgMaLmRISwG0jovxTqCbHf44iTkiUcfxETwdHx1BcM5diHFCP8vhvHM43Lfx@4@OaNhx7Pz40ef8hv2IHNG449gRjTqQ@0QXzImuoMDJM05nmWBO8PMRn9yFOC@@d3F/7cmG6548Yx0MnbynR9fSk2C9S/dHTJgLupEhh/sYCD15pulTXP1xdYUnWultMpsDcDGHD5Q5WgNYemJdz5HPB5ocwQ/MHxyuJaw8uxxxF@6UAkHx@J2DdCOtcXaX0xkNOJ1u5wkg@UDO1kIWnZh2Qt8q91jRQ@7jAccq8664D3rXyBcHyl/Roo@ODZPT8YwLSeoYOSJxB/bGZ4bFX7ckn7w@1nt81A2fnv2TV9d/90/2Xft98UVZbV2EpQ6eqR7eBh@KoxPcK3@inp@eT8/sRC/QYsF5fCsavkGo7zmkDp2YB87gzgBPMpHs15KrznYyTR34gmpIPTg8PKQOThtnjqCj4n9YD16d0WT48w6PjeKxRP/dw@kHzz9oZMvnP/u0GsQFwmlKF/AKxB4@lNkaYYqFcZn0kXHg@QdekAiVAJzUCR6ycBzgysfLUAGjeNevlaHTHw7ICBSqPokThUxBH1/iCUcXd1wnJ5Pc3oPY/FCW5KdY0HdGpmywWIN0PGv1@LfRb2PfXjYrzUruE3McO44RTt7d2cXvZZ2sk5TMA/oETZhUy1IHxvdqmP1BKZ4cHGvOYMgZXJfHXeLAyjwbdR@cBaJ@g1sc3NvLqV0h8Ly3ptcC7EF795rtvEzJ8DUkFfudXr8vBX7n8rvvD2na6VwndXj29AXX8@3p6fMpvp5tB749Pz@fvvonj831Bswm/B8mN/6Hg/sffKfW/ym@pSsWdxyRsMN98F3iDErT@Pbh24cDUCpx5AiEHbirQVtjGtrKRDlSyJ9gHOG/bzceRxD9aP0mHJ0aKHwGfRDwo2n6zn0VAPslHo/EIgfUb2n6vVUjELqeRhUFQTcm433zqElduuTwHLOynksFx@VkiY8a/LQ653ll6CBs6eCFAtjU2fazrZ8tL3I8@q7fwqDxqlbsC9YyPkibnNOPRKxVXXjQzySrE9ER3jqDF@@7qSfqK8A14U2yIBZuJxT1FV6ZiV9dKzgv@sYw3bhbxbipr76y2wjD9BvmA0aOI9mePvaEeqYwe7hez0DkoEU8Gmyt@OfwOkdVszaYygtkRTJIW2fZbGSxPk53i@AjJFpUQG6OEEmRUI4zZyX/lQXWnYiYlFyhlIU40D0TyVIJO7ZD7@JjSEn2PohuO3HEgBfGgsEJpwg4BgR04OkiuN1jvK2AdxFID2JxuEiWXAAUmLBeQokXiXbEW/x6D9ExepGXVQMQW6m7rBygowc7WTsPq6YXZwJYiHNH2jbSROt93muXHj546fbejZ5Wi5ddOBT6x4HN6mobFxSG9QUBEpEf9@wjFRMbNhNs7L0XivbEWgTrWsPZPhtGPVNHpnd8YhWVdkJduHj3E56SP/lh/M03/Lfa7fj@xD1OmPjp8YyhoR25JAvkyEyMEyAe2q10f2LeejzSfWLsvnDhd3xyKQPAosVsw23nDXKuJIAWvGzHcHuXt4rvB@Xem7tVPEDyxHt0k1h6uQTjncNPAitF9j4mWDsfkKaZWHqUE@4Ufnh1wM4CY7A2PNzJjheOMnLJieUtd58AfsgQ0ePJQWaATuNW9nju3ZC4DIGvI57I33zDeeSz@Yns87kx1LfBj7lbExz3ngR@P3Zxp/OPy9sJxD92wTMBychuIB7i2bx@XtMO9J0Aj60y3ZBu0TjH5M2BvHEicXTz8ejmKPHhw/J27hvfey32HzMbacDEzzHxJ1sLuF1HN270giVk@N7l@Fo6/tp/ZCCHV/J4gMlebSumReHRDYRoHs@K6mesL8nB5quVJ1jC7EXH1rGO5Eg3MuFDjss0yImsZg9vv4C4SYOXJBvc2jejSdBv5vBJ6V5yXClHIHCY/aEFHHg3//iRWiVtr3OFlLFy6QqIw/1vcs62jucSyEc7rJ1in9Ov@9TwSueue531wk0WQQ83GNmqrkQ1kQpn6PwtBsFq4Il5PrE0lrW6GZQN0R4AQ7QHhvNhLYKZZOsJGzJhB0JprQoIYmE9IVq7HPGJgAbWT9geXtd8UCEWGVCZ95AheYcJoptAniRwIemUpAcOqCrUV5AJTAPOg3SPzkCRoW@@QfbraQI67VHcFmAwDDf0sBjoFaWQ@BdQCjgwlUOQUawPSSJA21c4BK/e30ko9I9LyN5844IInqHX2oPjJ3twXBPFsLaeYb65LTJwWXz11dCTCNkEwT/paEB8CHv@7YHd3B@jdOWy2mxka5fJOtyhnxTbPpF4der/q7O@NXyGd1dSyAp0nquxQqfII@QC29XEZ7bhb3r0ULFZQoFAOePFJ6wA6w@skThoUI/XmASDnF5p@FW9T8@kkUTvfj0If3@BLHYn3yryrY4uxuSQxlnebIjb7Icz8NgXNOb2sRA7pwSPBcOwjzD3rb4KQ/blkq2BY7zDDWqhfeQ5WUe4WgpFFt7h6S4vWc6pS32JfOpjYCHYiU8OmzWt6KR@UPio8h5ncliiqXiMYY4R48UOduUIrBzBlSO0coRXjsjKEV05YitH3HawK8yshRk6tcFgZOOMbpyxjTO@doaYjXODIRTYOIMbZ2jjDG@cm9RC69QiMYIXHay4SaquoOMwNhRbheENrYpJPMOAhn3pGQJCA68gIXrolSekF9v1jMYZO6ECXcFAgUBk8w7aZwWbcFlUeS06vFbK1pvtCW0VZfXViMBmdR20UnaOv80AQuc@RniDD0WB2kW8LHBgDAgmWCmJHMi/4D62Nr7qi@PNJh@MIcGu3yE6PooY4rDkMyOW@OwJDuwLtrAF9mKzdg6jNWO2dkjZRFpUHu@0tBbG0I7fNtYPWMFijr4BEbAgcBnsbqlapdnQJ3uTDL6f5A7CvUm@IsrCG94XC/PGRZAnVlFJ@0@wJVbpWXaKQEobzAD7m1JEBl4UKN4BnXhijx2/@eWf/m/oN7/841@jH//81//vf/qfsfs/4tv/DjYLCqwBfv7H@PZv8O1f4duf49ufbEUi8MFjx49/@it4/Z/@PfrxZ39sBf3Lv3B4Q2tEEIK9NjF/8U/x7ffx7f90eMNrwF/8oQWIozi8z9SOaeUCqJ//NUKQGsayRvanf4mQwwMGhsuWvFurjt9v7Ze0EKzZcEtc9y/DrTs@kh94zLg9DsBrv7GbNw8uAPcWcp3DH0na1D0wZ6zV91hL8xw/wHvibC/VwPYPj00Y1fD3Qd5mPTB67NENJ@T@99AxcnowDHiTjd8JS4fb@bfz7diEYliPgwbq8DHiNirywYI1JdC9pUC@SU9gYfhxt4X0SFlLRmz@lvFH2FYNiGMlWeT8dspOaxUbOj3I/pYNOdB/1dXFQoubIWvjNDnHnrI3bbFbCe6omxfFBqm89IEu42Yr5XZU4iGMNSgSiLbmN2YsfiFc8L5Etyk5u9pkK7kXFQZfXTAxR9saaZ1QAjkcn4HFnLbh3djiCu7CW/TaALfMcfB@Z2PmPmDH9fW1g9ryY7AM6T0XwbCVKUtlrIPY3aDAVlBgKwhotnASXRMOBF7QQBoOrBd3NyFb0bZU1G60jXDhmrMqB0wG9AWtUU2vKE@MQeI1aqKRd5Xda@RbKNn7hF1P7hSic86Qw/0qAuDcjZN4WZb7UTOvYF4X1P6YmNs7Pjul9TamnThblYJwj3rJpXXJsfF9Jbeb4Duo2XvPFyYUYP6RCfm@MKFI@PMJvSxWHHcH/dv8/bzaWamJtYbfILMq/sFOA4Wbxj8F0duoI0yxTpwuN3R5knaXpztTkWvPR4vAn14dqbbzpSJ966A13Ikpq6ZgDQ980lTocqjYCt760uG@z5vaHxbsK6ouGNsbriVrS5rixFv@ebWvQKvmxUe7SfZnuPBsvHW4y267sm7ZbCs0bX08EaO2GIUtz4cHSZHMhwcwPmXRvWEgfvXzeJ@Qk8JfXQTXVnzX2rStaC4VH1Fpuj@Pk9i7VrSGxI9cFc0OdEIiSQQdOl6QofOFBviDLIZqsQRn0fpEC1ikXdPlxkwcqGO1LygqPu0Ax36BvrDBjQniNI3Q4kWcF/FbFNmdaBfv5dx21IufHBVdBPAnhVbxA7sIdpjhRfpLHmPO6nuSe3gzOSvaKr36T6e3vk1v/X16RUk3zJc0E0882oOfPy3poGuDAQA3ZAQ/T4bXPuDkFTk7pKy98cfArAhfTGJPMHho/jClSQBN2uB@EeTDu34z4G1NeOst/r9fgKvo2S8tPmLM1hegb8bk2z2ki2aQ450UXnABeMGNdc/r5NainfnCtOyODunheZGDKC4FbzeDiqlpgmI4VpArxJ@RebxM6JXck7VDCStwD0361ItGgbeLKPPQE2RuIfRcNqR3C@8qxzWB6xF99WUZx4qOKD3V@gKci/GyO6YY2RZMgI7fEBnOO3W73xYrC0RaSw@ZjCMUFt7mHxm4e6ma8SBowpoDUXXQoAfk5CByXpO20BbWUQKy9eFZW49a7Y9VkmV8wsJnGQJ8sL4CxXo3ybrfU5811zpLX9AirGH9u1nGu4VXGPF@3ddl@NNY9PmcklGGdaTEqpR3rJO3Slx6r8S3pGIlk5ZV8mUi@Tmh@2KZ2xI1C9lGhaV/WhPyCnOak2Wed21jtHzeLTFVeaUTsB8uMVV5o1V52KNQ1zGJpjPxJzYSln3hpiRwFuA5hWcLnhgh9EEfLIFa5Q3btashLxIy5rQtq8X2ueWxLbrFRff2POIWFLVy44Hc53Wa/Jtp8q/S5HfSXNeA3SS3gCh@J0m7FHDxvFcEsiCab2hnHIR77vB4T23Dpaicjuden5yS81jyIufUeQwK2Sk4j7MuUMrOnvM4QxyG87hOHCPn8QU4NnXL@b3zeFUtMIAOr8TxCfvbKhy/887jtMv9TJHPja/S9TuP12UKMB@tV8KRZ2t4tWvP@qvrUVUBf94PG5VehCXGgIeKs3V77yU/Bv4JqH0cHwR@SKDAEQHGHZCdRmOrxbDSgWbDT75n7NrXfByvhqbs8Y3NGAqEexJbgypYSiZEHzkPnLvKyCIMh5LBR3gCgVhvHu@nCLGvemafI8dOXcIfVgRm76ZPuOcn9kDPRcJvAXh7EEfexF@V1y4KqwC/jE4c@S06X5GzSo5QhBcDuPeQhZn6nfOdTOGyfnG0m1X62yX0eowAF6JvBWKVEkG7pdPBhsO2KUlMU7VdISGheLZP2o6DL7tSYul9EY1oBbtmvhFMvO2cYcWwXfnd72VnKx4mbUcF4cBb5t6qZet2gehiHLTRdVuWqlX5gIQtndMjZ60IWGwztpPAWerGS9qKt5qhVVwrSaK5dtUkRPbjnZwTzrRS38zL4P2dP637uooJJjjQiBFsxVynYulX9SfY76plv68M6hUTXiSwz7De35S@Nq/fbWVfUC5vkn1dgDjQizLuvcbROoUNy6F3sGWZvydrr0x8/OU1y8i3El1jf2Htr9i27hN8hm8v@xYWLmwl6NNdzxEemB0F3mbUa4tEnvpXRosfp2TjsTK@pnSTtfdptTK@r4hxCG6j4fGTC1jfLeDtwsP4SAb0Fyy3ajn@QDaZp1jXbfJJ5c3MhTXroOJVYuuDCrc8Qd2T9WvrJVrgUXmoZSrlUgca3Wg06n49FYFrLcTdtOPUu9ME625LwIvPmrK@iKzilTS6@eFOcbxeUkY8wBjgyLyNJX52HXfbumxLn7@ouxDPgt3iqI1rtKkG3I5WwqYOh5tsyeardeq/64izkazMW@C3l/TW8KwRlg48ofPwQJqvhwe8OOfhwW7FcNGsp5F@e2B/@C@wWa9BHeyuZiIWl/HqQBc8ADAZW58wtgfg7KNarHUoB/hry@Yq9jrWRDGl1WIHPD5kfzHZmst3BVk8OlEQ1z6EDrwowxUI4S5sIIw3xluxMDQe@CRLK@10PliGDj6x2NBUhZw5Sc7xImY7Pj/ZWA29ErInyowjy0CsVMh@/i2KrAVZq3kx6zvNCjmLF@LiPWFkCHnFGy8S@n4y4xOIQ5djJGnWUYTrpR@Gm0QiBJM1WsDjriyMgaQ6yO6e0eRLCUplkJP6fRAk2v6UhbXApcFBVJ8q@tKrI3YOUIuTpd7qsFd7TRg5aNkeBwZ2unbOSDJQIALWVNwLnN38gLF4mQzC5yAxZJEWgYJfFB5RyxnzbsX94Fq4d5/s6nJjfB9cD7hkrc2gko4/WzHllC0@23tEt4am7UlLoge2Zi5Xx31R9vFsCTJP6cdr1DSX48CxOgQNO61lE5zMr04PcuFzq46prxSiePAKMMRba2vAwFWw0Uam19zrJakK@hoFA@Q7vJAesVJJsoDDmtnbwQ5hEBUTa63usxWM4@ue42s8mUh9dYB1oSVrOP5KlLGbHPu6kWX0wUZnTajgqmxVgdVLeOslCF2Nr/Yk/MHl8AAWj8Pt2MEE8Pbsx1eW5n0dFZSi@7d0oxdp59RkMtkYs3rtPNlPDpK1DrynmJKnPQxlaTqbl3vJTKG7OFejjakYYBqdq1Q36KlGe3NNyo/TeS1LSaHO2HMTnMfzoWU4HUwneeZaPC@JoWj6Wrw2hKQsxOnpcHTVE2pal9UN6aJ8Wa4t6VzzqtW/Goo37fYwqtQprXaT6l/NhatYW5m2mvGCcSW00mVzVB6aE3ZRibYjzZlipFqN1KC4KMxG80JE7Ujh9JUQbYlafsYvwhqfb1I308YgUs8vRnF23Fsk00avE/V46E461Y/l@d6NWKynL3p9PdwNj@pxLjgdF0VtMbjIK4@lYbo@5T3aMFeITCmlWpjOhFB71JXzyk2t1epmUtXZiDVutN4w1L6cmN2YHgkGJ0lhMAyFCxNTj5VSyYuomUkWWjn5umXeLFqxKmXmzUa0WeTjsmdaMfngJNOkDaY1L0oX9VkkH2ioeaUoF4bV0fnkvCprk1EmJFUa45Dev8511UAgf1Wf5jslSg8V251YbRiIZfg5T1@EVXUcbMTLJf1yPkk9VoR2mq@nhG6ESYWvs@zwsrLgK9NSrdauau3mOGpcsPJNjhlSlWu@nkyNcqVxjG2UF4XYeaE@SacL82k3IPbV5KTXDl5eR2alslBoX9HBPDcxLz1SuiLTw2LRWLSaF4XrsnED1fqyKIXExTzVSuniYyZtXNZKdFkfDeqhodLTWlEprfLFaiFkFkbJ/Kx9Ey@kRoJY7Y7UUaMttyemlBnSOWqRHl01u8IsJy1nXDZUal3Rw2yNN6PJfrBOD0WxO5IrxrJ/Xlr265NuvxevnDMZ4fGil2qFa1mNvcwZobKyoDqNlCgta1ciO6rG84WbbjYpXSrhdFXQquf56TwQ6EhidRZesvPrYS4kzfkQU6qkri89V8VAzVPypFJVNVjpU4FM7rzdD1941JywpEsi9xhNe/TJJDTPTPDH50tNRdbHYZmJ5RqeQdTQ2/HLy1nXKFzX0m1eXsZuLkejyE2Nup4WDFUPxIq5ZJyujhj9nBuWCzdRScmFZqlzORsvtJfNmJktTeRYvtTPFGt6pjHmr@PZfn2xGPVjRaFaGiUpIZap1Ybdfqs779SN6oK5DPHDrid7ni0/9qEet@q5QLGZivQntWDrIqNMq42cZ6let0taujxis9XYJNKIBsfUdF6MJeumImmZ88t45GoilbLJTL@ZZlVBuH7kL9gRV28smJgR1a9y11ea4TEbXTXUHaSCi6vLDt26MYxwXqJu5u1IITnS@Yve3Cwa0YYSUCtXDHsllptyeNqWHjtVdZgc0xfN6yXdnS1z86rJm/WRGu5Fw6PzufGoLy/0CyrWGXJys5xWS0M@ctGRllE6zCqNTlq85DvFAJNs9vOXQi4/7S@bwjgwzD9O8jzHG9Vkp3suR6ZzzSMGY9MS1Si3r/vRx0emK5Q7cSk5ataqBTPQ4OhJp14KP5Y6hpHjmwUpFZKUSSbVOR@N0zcLrmHMl5NGpCuLi6oeYLLUvNy5bPFDtW/kjBt@uLzO3SiXk0DkujIUo2ZvxI4lttQSmWhZq3kynqp83u0vIq2JMOXBMtSuChqbSg6HFarCjqPT1CJumMq5cVHupotJKZksxQJXWiCaH6XP8/Oe1Gq2yvkep4ZuuulgpNLtM4FeqpztV0PjfrRajoZKaarRXVzV2F4mJrEDTk4Pi4uQFi8FUhG6Navlr4aNgVKW08n2XEwF@YY6i7Y5UWkKy0iUvmQ8w0G8qCSZUDVCNc2M2SzlZkGPclG4DFQXC/66y02CnPjYMTx8ZzlYVloCp8qD0mONbbQmpbQ0HLYiKb7BVFJ1ZrI0ZpxWqlLxTFVhM6X5NDcb1NuMoWXyWqw7L/fS1arQ1XpBTexWknORmbbbN1dXzYoyvr4a52vRbmXZ44bhlinWIpW5ST2CydOalpq57jwjGuKwNn1UzueT6xYdap6PS83e1DOM33SmQem6wpTKqZbITQpX/ajZLM@1y6IsyvQ4UOnT1KxZXS5NIalmy7PLzlxsLZdJKWU8svMLmiudFzLXpieezSUzlUad0@VK5byUSXLj2eWsdB31CMv6ZS8sjR5vqKqiyAH9pi5HU0zQCDTDmWWaH54zk/PUuFFsxFmNbeZbl5cX7EDmx3y0U8lE2pd8O5ksXiyKIteqVrXqRbNBVTzK9c1Ng6405FJcLBVqDTVcmOqX7XaUm6nJK44phMbdWWmeml1OJu1xvOjpmAIXVJeCwNZmcokW8iA7MUqYTKvpctVYBB6Xw8f@NKNet@JJ7TySTC/E3lSYLplkZuqhjdx81otIWizQ6MzPxQ5/2e9f1FKDoDbVGpF0mCrGxUul1U0PLuML4SJfauUmplDvdUOSx2C0YeMq2TSa/EI65yODadPoyFD5RC3cSKXjhnyTiV3okoeJ8SmKb19yVbo0CF@Xiz11lp5fthYZ6HLEWLHKhNWF0prERkr@wkhdtB8vYrF@s5sfQcKTwc2Al5qeVK8rXIlymbq5vmiNstVJix5eXV9Gq828J7YM6uePvDo45@KLxrLCMIIY708Lk3lQK/Gx89hFhZeL83KtKQr9SD1wJZ8rSyqjRAdMUmRn05lCexbhVCzbF1PNsqJnmnw@KqhVjqbn7Ruz0r6OXQTOmSumPp4xAeNyRjNiR5EWnXKnE@hRqalxobXr7DTryZvJTn1Y489lutyuFZbqopQNGM1kOS1eTGYLrbSQ9OANXzpPy1VeYsEsCUf6Db05WqamXaotzkvpVCx6E8iDBBmGHJ91QpzAG1p/PqRLl5O8PB9ORi3dM57TNc9NZx6OD1oDg@ZLpUa5MMvqYbVoDBUqEuED@bauRY3a43hRSJuZQasph9LxVr9byXfoy4Z4Eb9K12@iQrhKFx6FeLseYfhSuM3TbE0dT01okfj@iCotmJ7Oy4LORSeVx3B2MvH0FtOJ6dFuoucXsXZ/lGanPOcJJrvqIzdvFWVGKkeFvlFpz6bXuTZYiEpr2lSo3E1TC15IebGeb1UuR2w1WVuadCre5q9D/Y7Oioo4rQXNcLEg9KO8mMnejIaZfOGxwHTER2bGyvrVVTCXZ6mo6EmZak@mW1falbIMcEKyU4ldznrL9HhQFoV8IZDRO7VIr37ByVloRqXHEqO1cuelm15XHtCiqlTqNYahbiKBbPu69shOe1fVZUOd5/V@MVmVg9diQVGr1y02c6XT5Wgqd5Ue1m7Si1ikqstdodGPNZSx5zyo8lxSKUWoqDAVUq023RSkIBudL7vcSKDZm/ZoFMvTy4ixpJOKMRvG@st493zMtm/K6nljMaLPx/ObauqanQgelq3yGnVlLqvh8/O252Jx3iz05WZB5GluvBga@dREKM66V5GkJ6YxDU@21xrMS9W@1s7S0W43xtaDwXbIfOxVF8ZVmWplSvlgNLMw52J2NCnPY3ktGakv5s2rUGh0M5xXYvVILTxnp@oom9Jy/TCtXhtRZd7I93MpISteisblssuPqchyUi7kYllPWOA61c4NI2bpx3pPNgd9sXFxHaxHaD6cr1RnNzeZJD2OisNsQT6HNnHGXc4X9WFn1L2qGEGJUisdTyGyjCzrN1flnlJtFy8H3Vk/Gq3q@dYwPll2tJpU82jLZqGrnmeqYzmzvAaBi9Ti4WFTzjbb0nWmxlQoM9JOzsAGZ1MladGnC2HmQlSY4nx8Hr8etyOjzqiVntY689EwUo@G1YmwjJrtx/BEaEY7xXGd5rud2cATOKfU@nJxnb0K6aXyTCuZVVW4YGKB0s2oOc5Omp5x@iLXNdNtRusG2qXZxJMOg1UQu2zFA@XuxTBVGJ1fGfmrQJxq5KTFJDY8j5x7qtCYTIZGJdaSA/KUbtNyazYVRmOGK2e4lj7vNnOlXrkXiNGaR4rOzIvIY7FTveFMLaTQlLGI9GacJ58FCyIjdcJ1T8vUmDH0RZjrafBC6QcDhnJdr/NmWo2OmsG4EMrpLUVtzdVhKyBdnUdHM166GFIpYdkLyc1au1eeL2e9@CjU4@rTZjJ3rbSDaUUbzA2djcQvAi3usTrWgxVTq5aafEq5GnOcOPPM5VTmUq9PqV6/nOy1c48TcdoKVZKh5OK6x4QmN9Mhqyyvs53AsNpNDsRZrR1a1mbBVO@cVWpjSRvrAZpptJTsKDZv5oULqrjMCotB7CpVbYWaF8P4KCj3R/UqsxhVJJG/uTEmbKHTL12xvUK4lbqKj/KikRSizbhYHNLzcrdyE0n3hBBDeQaFMR1Il/hgMXvtMYu8HH6UlmzZXMZFZVFuSt16f5rUSr1hc1JO5ekUG5iezyvjYL5GBydcahzLXOgdXaaEbDg5b1YuI8bgJmm2Qmo1MI1pN1Wpfx3oVQccP2YiMdDBl73uzaKZrKVmpU45XzeSSn8pePTZhXJeyOVSCpUX2@VH45FTxUky1KyUOlePV0m93wh3TaPAzh8FerFQKsU0zy86yYIxKreKdaUQZca91GX0atArKU21KgUvKD4eHV1HaaXOFyeMEKomQ7nH1jn/WJhGaupIMflG9oY1yzVQdoVws6J1ZuNlesCI82Aoe21U@j3tBmrrcEkFJvlap1cTh8p8ViuarYvguM6OWjN5FFE4zRPKxisVju0HcScsfK0qY1W@6JvX9fL0QqfpwTIyEbRz4UKiSgGtnyzUIsUAd37eycSb7PixJARil6FJchao1C49SljQMoX@WGbSo9pQuJKgy9COVIdFpl6Wmv2bSfo6vqhTy05XjCvF9ky9SI9mmdF02GjOg9C9arRKhlGvXZu9wjTQLUblbmXQa2Ry6Ss@zXFGtKKks5WRNml1x7N8KEwNc8Hr4WW0KPUjo2hBWHQuJlq8WlwW0oN8yNNRijGzw5nyY0UePpa7ptl9jEqt@lWRbqeivMI8LqLm9aBNG1Q@Ns6eh4TosjBgo01lPJ1MepWaohYW1atLYHM0EGycd@mk1r6qmq1eXuCv802w9IuqUKhfF7X6@XW@N@kplBwE8U3T@sV5ychdZ0Y37KxQW3Ql1jOqXMwq4WhYjHc90/C4PJhkwuF2dFwsT3MZTY/ML0Hr96uLakmolS8pdnzZyY48RZFlY/rlsjUN1ZLCdaR7ORNnoXAmOVcGsViTmV8Vz/mrWFcrzMbNItu/omc38ZEx5ppcLcmrYoVKPWrBRWZuZplw9iKSv74ShpFZLzsJFJKzersQMeNlsd0OPc5qs5FQzrFiYz6dBaq5ypWphMLz1tXN6AJKIUzx/flVNipchoQeIy1v0npO7SpNLsnQRTowa7auPGpfeSwLnlE1kAtqkSwzr3LQM75JTYq9SLc5lNvnqXx8QPVCfNbTMCKFm8jj9eOlpF8PPdExqJyYWJteXYJJ0jWbjdD8Sox32GUrHWtz3dySzV7QyVA@P4kXAoFiKV7qUEY9PAZpeZwFrosZOXBVbTVCE0@mnJn3BvWbZi09u4zddNhxtV2fFnFnLEgzM7EyrDUX5dy8KQmR7KiWFVOUp3A1MypxTaxlWlmdrvbEXGg4yp/nzoXJBT@ZZxUP0y80F9PHyViIFS9lTtCVXM0cJPlgJzYKzvmClny8aFGLPJctsulYK6aPJL44LDeNoTFta6KUDD2G5x6zNqxKF@FMrXGtDJuDclnn05eBqCFkRvVx5KY5nHenQrZXpEQzPuXl@Xk5YiqpRU66bl5eFXt1ZsFXY8VyTp8zXTr3WGemJt2M1auNfresS6UhNJyeTlNVYzKoFHOgXlGcNigws1byohfrG@lzJlYqzitNqexhrrK1YSZgTHUPPRhXApmlmi0GxVm0X7u6GDN6etobeC6qUfpmmFJnZSps9oJtzhjFayLb6bRoLVtbGsZlrNn1XFzJtFAL3ERT@SXb6Aa13mTQiXXG59PHTufysduq56E4rz1CpH75SPWvLvJGVIzzbK@ZSpeS6lRjivq4JobGJbXTDHRET2eeKcweAxdMbljosuXyYLlM8UW9rcQy4@5lmlsMm7EWFcxWmN5NUNCKzcxjJzeYDPl0ac4Hr9W84bkOleeTcz0WjbCh@JQzgq3xuOWJJWXJEw0OFoNAKjuNZOieXmtT2Yon3VZVqAW1mwhXpo1QryybRjPaqGfjtXQunS9dZK/FUrxe4K6vPZ2rQjqbbESKF4NR6KLDGik6dTkY1gPUsJQe9WjTjE2kupQzsud6Zj64GV2NJ91ZdFoyOkvlgptI/TErctqoXVKikeRV6zFcYYLZSzp7s5SVQDQ8j1M9XuwVabk2um7HpGye7sgD6EBnQP5H15cTnRd1YxBvQ84vl0o03az0W3peHlSBQrk70XhxHJdGAyF4Q9XoeiwXbcsXIl/p1MbRTle6bhSDUXEyh/5rJ7O8EDM0lHqzUx9MmOtIFkzXUOix0B6Mr6blllELZ1qNUjVEtR5rGZEtZEul1o3ZY8sVpp@bms1oLJ9l@XFqVM4uUt1UYZbjm@28Z@gJNHr8NNdKytlWjzPmixsmzuhJcUhFhpHLlJhhzVm4JeqhdHFQCXJyQZ1XijFtXKsWA6li9kpURzqTukqurkhrER9L4UVfTCbPW4VOuk8lr9KZYaAlGnxN8cwKBCyVk7nf/uSjQgRdVwgYNVWlHv4ilCHYx1ycvHPwBDl5Am9v3zl3Ai/22T5IQLT3V1sflvU6mniH8LGVCJnb9OOvheCpxZOXc4s@dnWcAHngczzQEflCiLgzEerQceQ1GR8k5T0CyIwnmUHB82Bke/LXxjH8gAbvCiWwieyocxHeuD9LG@EIPucDHyDK3J9sTXm62G1qMIFQZJwiAj@9jq/xqQrfQEQyBZyt5Nz7pvWZk534QJyhKeSkEYfP7yBR7VMxMKZdFFZpYv/12QwUOZBlNbH2zvfPOJqNMZE4Od8DKV7TO76N33uP@IQDCabEKWNjos96o746mIpIRtqwO@cXy0eEwiGEjzoKfGMdLspGEjQ52TlKzsmMk8OgD1dne5LD7PG5XuScRnyUqBOh9aFWJx@Qmzi8@HbsOHklpej/K@5at9pIkvRv6ikSYRvJ6Irtnl4E2AIE1gy3QcJuDqZxSSqg2pJKo5IAjc2P3R/7AvsA@3DzIL3xRWRmVekC9MyeM9NnTCkvkZGRkZGRkZkRr7uGC8XJR/f8p4uN3kax3D3vXZR7KyuZ4crGcKW0kkbCq1Km3B/pm4jnwwt@tV94rQ7M03pEB8Hd3@BKHQe91k2wHCqOTh9/c8L@y8wE6rr9@Hy69VrDYBBPuQI/ud3ERJxOwimxO1HTD0y54bjv4ejOeiXoBMS/@Gdh9NPb8nQ@eriwABcaZX13It6B705/1Oz4rTVngemJI3A8p19b005hWgp8u7DAab4kCi7KD9PILpvcVtAf68q@FLk0fVmPgdxM42w1k31OSVOqSTx5iVhuAyomRYS8ieKKQPPRaEawwve@17PnoPDjkynDy4laNHnG4w/Kg2/Y787lUPnspYf@rCtdlH1gqIz2OMGp5z4evfFVgs1lyVr4bdTt8/lzXvDVFEGg2su@6w9szXw4auJ1ryqBGL5BGiOAjwe4f7t1h158aMxY4OIbP75CfwDvmKMNEcItF1G@STbi8QHgtQOusyCRkNNqGMjFSkFD1@VuZPRQE@Hgd325v7ym@B5cmZL4SLQcy/2NctHXOdldyu66w5s52TeAPQrnZQ8oG/GR52T7lC1vImfnB5QvJ/1zCgxxy5PY9XIYXA5dv5MWhx5wBfIgAjutVlYMYS0LKBkYGY9kfaVdo6hFGR1htgR70fxktpICYOm0njz4HXEL58ItfVr4Itam0ER9V082pi9HEokvuSUSu2g/8zoBX8UQoPlHolRN55vGZbRtRxP8k6dl5xqjTcR6o378eAwzzYhJ/itdGO6TEcI93FgPhVoRHAnfGo2rVPq7rjS7jnYdE5du5o5E1A8zKVcjESJzK5rXV36vTW0Q4MV4Mq48ZdT7KOU8vFBrVnpEdJRp8TQdV6e4BzeieEZmVTP6bD2fqi74nmq6tCI3I2EBP2FueYqcoS2dS5bepNKWmhN81krwjJ6lf7Szz@vNEuHHk5ppUxZB2yLVcFMjOAM9V8Y1LhME2IvlNUlHsFk/CcyfA0z86V0SgOE64YCVzYhxsyb6vby8SSU5X1x9m@Ur5lLkISKTEVbPodP/w@QC4fSSPUL8vaRIUjNIM1Xc9hv02pycchPdE0k/u3Pn8qh5@f0ycFTT/MRc955WyTVVVNZxU1k9PC2H/jnKfI@GL6HvhOn5ssIMuuHE57DgwxxCP8lkyS6sXqgExYECS4YnliR2Qjh7UYqu1l@aFHPtUub2XA0MWJWT@cBZAJoMUpTjtbJa59qMRKf2vng5NMpNNtLCEPZWuIJU9rITF@fYzu3y4h1Pta6jmCLxHLxkh4Y5MJj5V0a3JTXY1Mu3LjHMQmTQk@b0dRC000Zh0goDQzAeOqhQVtxZWbVK1MuoeWpOK73qWnv5MOtumVIWdRKvK5QA5VPzJpB4fc3TpoxpE9Nv/JCjMnM@ViNqyrw@wGVFkT5qbTIdpa0KtDCzkpH48EnGniu1nOeVOCEeUttuDxdDMRyytV5PId0OBMps0kY78m/JY/Aww8ogPjy1d8vv8a2LX/bz0IntoJtbkJmyxWZ9PYVmLMM//L60WBiFg0LT7xW83i0p1c2xs6S8ngQGXFOj4VXuZ1wUrpzsfdLShO9l8yVEYhMaKbSW73l3aZQhzRleRFMZR3zS8aXFkgM3xHxvvOPdtknrF48t/SC853/HtFko5kf9YcA5uiH2Xad@@D8if6pFfkWkdwwanXWGE5VJ432BpI7lrmSuJApSCS6WMzEQ56jJAjf1JZXC@AFRfZ/0/MIJ857bugES4L0fsp2i4WJOfnBCM/TwtQZS4PEKfXbEy0Sf746iCdZOwjH/pu7jdwkfksJXXMH3ep/i8IVg5HSCoA8mx1VQ1F8nAgjhF@qNnerJSV5HVJIb67jlLveY8USQHdZxdAZ7jRe31eEuUAZlAZ0FbGlvIwLO8pdphGY1mTAV7kBOoRX8EUoPciX@NdUNWz4jxZkk/NxJ/wpBy6L26tEnPQq0i6qlY9VyppopHCPFwpPUcFstOII48LoBYbztdTqEtNBiISIHPkER0/6KbT88R5sXFnnJz03l5xL5eckXpKJS@dbNICq0Fi@UWvoelXtQqahYdqqtDUWdrh2yd6l8MIjhXX6sbJinTZofFd60QylcaTPWExm5WM6vM0ZfchYTdSyD2/xzydf8vapH3mKZKPsh2T7@OnqAPPbBoJ8sTnBpvud33ov50eawhFVwqyTVMd7MdjIptUFEi5MciQliYp62mxsRlJWSkTg8Z1Kb6x9SeW2Sep@eREMCAk5NrBlzJEYlbnOFCXfPKwm1w9mLMRAME4ymzMzdNJXHuvI4BhalFk2zjvEUmpzg1LXJKb6Ba90/8I@Z7EnkTLml2ZkLgvm9dF5eWiQJxEJ3MTWbTElpMhyMPEnUnXpkFYnaHk9CnC0kDgPsQFs3kBS2TU/eg1wFo1570cqJuKAwkmKK7jZHUzoqUDLsO28Ikfng/F547ey5XdIKO969qkCndtkxv5N4bDP0wmFIc8CjDg5UOOr3O77266bu@DmHjg20@g6PESKIMaUh79TwQFTKZ/GlH8dQpbw6AuQ7vDOMMsLRNYKywxKM@OIkWq98AjnMO5XemD0Tsxu0VXny4qkR/LhCAHdo2xdDQkZOZg9bHqCl5R3zsEi6eiXzuzckFYg6HrDPQ7haXXOcv4781rftPbVaLP6pVHxTipHMmKqL@TdvVS2mIpmM1WKpWHxXeus420F/LE8b060MYL3NAWBW7WOh/0S86d0i/rdToRWDC4ak@ofe4NZr5x3nxGuzDbg5YoqAlUcgV8/4eUUK6Vbwd0/qbjfMKtp23UC84C/WZ/Fd22LHGlkHb4j63qDrD@WlUXDrt0FA827qKuh0gjs2ROPJktADlbrekIjyOqOSKLFfWo0L6y7sLpaogRAP7MCvGdyyH2lNBtJTfbjf5wdADpwoAkK8sV57AhNqr9Vx/S7YaQYC8LIUUcAgQF1rj1reozg4jMQfxEHpjrWD1gieeV0zMgWSfgHPFZru3sAn6RsRmEeFq8VwpwFufKzVVf1ot/G5clJV9H18cvSptlPdUVtnqvGxqraPjs84epj6eLRP0qWuKoc7lHrYOKltnTaOKCFVqVPNFGc4lcMzVf3l@KRar6ujE1U7ON6vETQCf1I5bNSq9ayqHW7vn9JivZdVBEEdHjXUfu2g1qBijaMst2qqOVE9dbSrDqon2x/pZ2Wrtl9rnHGLu7XGIRrbpdYq6rhy0qhtn@5XTtTx6cnxUb2q0DFnp1bf3q/UDqo7eWqf2lTVT9XDhqp/rOzvT3T06PNh9QTIJ3q5VSUsK1v7VW6J@7lTO6luN9Ch6GubiEcI7mdV/bi6XcNH9ZcqdadycpbVQOvVv55SIcpUO5WDyh51zkk/QRUal@3Tk@oBkCZK1E@36o1a47RRVXtHRztM63r15FNtu1ovK2f/qM4EO61XswpRYLlpgkHUonz63jqt15hutcMGrRmnx43a0WGGBvkzEYawrFDVHSbw0aH0loh0dHIGqKADD0BWff5YpfQT0JSpVQEV6kS17Ua8GDVIRGzEu6kOq3v7tb3q4XYV2UcA87lWr2ZowGp1FCCYaPdzhRo95V5jnAgv@SRmdQznZnk4VW1XVXY@1YC5Lk0cUK9pbmGybX/UNKe5XHBmHrk9eoA3fcqnTSGPO4nfPtqpksYnEWJSUfopLTo/Jw/vEnm00NhM@qlPQXmtumx7zdH1pd@7CrA1t9XkBLsbXmcRVSmDyL1fnEfii@uDcq6wtHR5@alySfvc@uVlJvucmgk0nqqhvbA@Viqj@9gJ3DZv8xO2pTihNl9pX@9Zcbwct7W8ssaHjCoU2p6uhseLAGzMRDooAQFrQzLyq0a3p2JN8hFz0lbEETMmjUXmeDMI6Z/ej@iHrA2xBBLOcm@hUMAeltFA5BNl8adGOCiIjgzC9wD8K24yH3ret@t0Md4ctvzaQJUxdbjskLaB1@nME9Wb3vVE9dxkfUYWb01ZWTHu4I2bdjBmwL80yZQel/yAe5YW0x7/yRhsuCFSCjPSFD9k1bdP0q@kOvyLiq0wU7auxDkcyEHll9pnbOaKq2/LE@kfbbrMLbw6R2wbWu/Oud4F//l4IQVogvnYfhFJ/LEcqRYKsTqklbE@aQvDV/0NCt35bVpTsVTfeLysw0O@uAuO16fFeODfx7EnMbx3UjnYOt3dJckJbN/@/O5PP5Ud7XF/MPwlK3/P0A5CbDJ1SYu@80lN46zYLNkmvWd3KlhOLLoPRg8FEXDSDBonuqTSWs@ZoiNIfA0xA6G7ISIM9BBkI4UgAYOUwvt8b9Ex/DpzZmoGSCe6mkFvuu49a/guqUrMAy3xktkZ86jd4x/AttPfTHHbIc1AmsW8bn84Js6lzQXLvdSucTjAext@Vowi@ZTh475r7iAJYSAz2QsD3uDzL83bsVEkvRYDjfnKw841CYnFSSxMkBYOuURNHAehmcGS6FPKL5rf6PNMBwdCFkI9VIZ1IuOurZkzwXvE5qwnhoZ8sblBQ/TqlW1pXcGQmtFIif0/GTomPhsYFbnQoCYAm5tHls42h43QH5Yz6rtwKrx6A05Zc6z@TZw7qzsaStm4RNe/TQQZJbCigDKcdGfbcEyRM1PEkjNBpn@JHgz/30iTGfDXacNJ0CNqsRz2eyPvmZRkqEIr2r0yUfw7c2Msdk0tomY86SwC8xAfmBvbMX0N714OlogEenTGJuFMQoqlZxAATA67Rnz@woEvT@Ibl3ZOH3juLshJ/6DX6vbTJiCXWSqm4F5kWefKmity@JGRI/yiijW3j/gqH9jPI8sMbLhIijXH6mWYEhgrJZY56HThNRs97Cxn1gQZSmaGR@xU1FPLTP57fcMoWmXaJveBVNH5wb7scQhiCiUEvjkBMQKE7z7FO6zJRm1uAtGZ/YanF7byK72KI9YliUBel1WD3XOE7hXvmbEUaV8acNqBJgHnZVvHbGp6wzssFx2Bzj5EImgq/ZLdmKARbYu0aoQRvpk8UZ0X2TuLPZspwa8W@9Petx5iLXti4jIl8okIUHEXrHl14HIwqM7z@p2KGl8BWTeT7dd67FelJeeVMM3xzp1awU7/ZRhRhDTOO2iXtA5FVHJb35CYMjzq3@X8e/rDbeV0z01MI9ozcMS6WUr/w9wNAXhl4g6sSn3pWSPSmixkGy@N@oIvmbv26wxf2s68QZ0i5CgFF2a1GgSUoTfhkub0bGP8Em51cPl0jTSnu7t80x113d6V2/U7Y751@ltw0yuEvVHYz/fHTiqVSloD4QgcLlII96GnPvu9dnAXqi2aDjAk1Q9P68dJw1/M8rUtli@l/kxtqC1u2ZkCfwWfSWFwNaSh8cpqrEOdDyJzD9sJtaWFzVpjJMAx1YAZiNrtWs147/BU7Xk9b0D64DHfuVT7fsvrkfggZYpvYYY3ImlQfBet13Xrahe6C1t2ysrz2ahjbXuObkBDy4K10jQVCeGBDqsI2/yYWD1mE8xPdzjqV9sYlW6CvvYGBKMplE0xcV6NOlkHsRs/1xofsRmXjTnbZmhZM7Y@2BJFdeqKsZY6M3B7wzERxZk03hDaT9lu8oqdARFEZz45eVPXRaz2Nsx@nZC6ijj1WgrwCkJT1fNvESyOzXDPGSO@Z6vNZhHdytq/YlbC1xnRkRg9Jxq9LGKG5rPq3X@ohgfeVccdt0U7LFUfofqbN6QHbgXhEEUPKkoVV0ulUq70Biba03olzxMB/zcRxByndnB8dNIgQmoX@YYx7JoJ4nPQLrmNReTIIXQX9f4rBLIpTxJz9SsTDyq48eObKsuJRWotRWPfcmHupR6GSXWYTbIwyQcDDhwGb1DEQonpSK3C6QFC9LGQREsx6FkOXaaDj8nSYvFkb35c4Stw6xBfdXAe@pUrcxoJAO@e06jWgHcGbe32nsak63Ut9v7QrO6uFHAmY55ZgoktlZhjObsMLYmol4nDaXu4IxEiekA3vG0NSLa4t8RyuMJiXGIRz7BsytjeuE2/49McILxaNwEWHBFXZiDYBBGPiObwiNtYO1iQGJcZ0QpodrWDri0qWDmOdQan0/vhuBWopWvaZmOnFfY9r82REkZ9CQWA/DzN8g6tHOImbi2KEeAsFfne5ICEDUKykOwbdeA7Fr7@mjLmjukNcZVxL9i4wbZeAFGP6kOepIjYlp6xw84qnPNmeNhdYgjUzYAQcxz9EYh@FodShBWNNzMEfzG7ZOGOqsPjPekHEBU5GFHYT2YAlpzqeskMAx59159TBYRJNywCEy4GDTLiJ0u@Ezaw5A/0F/dO4TQtLX2kzo0zlpi7PkJoim0gUNcB/kXhvKGYnBF6fEY45bjwHi55Cd5kydJ0SSplA4jESq7OgJmbCfPNbJg5DVMfVtZ6t@ywDbWYLaQX4g06IPkIQkTd3wuM6GW3cp1ADphs7687QRNxm0hSUGv4M85GAxtP5h1YgtDxXHEimIw3tW66pFHXb5uM7qLWaX54m2rdWCw2v/RkoHTGhswl9lmmeO3i6cSf@EfPKP5MJYJXQeuYiF4F9CSVZDfApjRInZJaU9HMxE2ceHndcrJKN1GlNFFFI5es0kxUWXUiT6UTo4saEP34m@yZ0Uv4VhKPgNqwA1R0uu697G6K7ICOzTQIGZnwiLd6oRkEBc9byvq0Q/ELJ3LRnDi2lzbMT76Cxze@Uy9SHPKqmIx3cG@u7rEY4FKJ/DG7Ae@ldYcymgz8w7p/zhhkdL/WuUovJqlshyXDSXR7gLda6XgrmTW11Hfl1BClQixs8abPmQY4pU/Rf69VWjeQiyMrheBWV4tCIjy7Xj6nrawMi5GDRSdamflXTMDRCDoiv/nKmCwD6XRiXhnJbWHK55TsJlBIF3DckiP@P0PS6yQVK0pMNNSh8CGMqVbyvHvanvEZM4Pg9cdarHWi@DS20kMjfx61fGFWjWQv5paeXEpmlYmtKpYKjxU2xLZ0mlt4/mrDpIMNAfJOisdItw8jsSadWYKXQyEZayn@kJ2dBi1fJFSSbDGhK3WzMwRwcsgNctmJXjkxV@a6h5PLiJNYORNMko79Qph29VIC2QmgjJOoBfrPG3Bcd4xP7LnlSlJOD/s8jrCwzLg/xha2sBn3x9hCCseG/XG2MLEMLWm5/iRfJEZCSIBLiXrHwDaluAwyGffxUvcTpRih8UXcl7nXSc/ANiZVta3TmVKVLIl06JJkG/znXgZmSTsaTbAjEe/cjsZF1Fta41rfvLb1yKx7b7dIm6nkkiCjORmIAJ02LfAYXWQQMttWIIktRjC9Z@7K3U32aL8sGxbegyJq1/VN8nVvAqxZVYqZaYXSeO@PkF@fiXxuOopCtMVam44Pb2@Xaaxx4SkYtFE65cw48XWewGolhlWyd7ERSpJ4DqTcsyDlngGpEIOkJ/YbWi/5c2mAOHXeUyC@fJmGwX9@pY2UhkGStu3DiI198J07fgrmIilbS3ynzpVbZbZCpCc/BeP9JAyOC3pjT@N04o0Lq9vfvUEwGZVjLmWTvDIDI4vV0jRaWaDFUpv3u7qcUZV4b5v/1rzx7U5g6emRFj/GujKuEt/YQ6ClpFd9Cyya/6U59MvGhjU5HwTxhBmGtGXnD06HPAghFiZ5KmYrxARZch@qM5KEeDx3UvjxbnXS@zECns6tlnmyJx/E4BMzOpWoayKxEhxntnCRcDKrlZFvs7ZnT7a/NLP9ftAnHedqJgJcvgs7vhilJkR6pJpObK2ftZbNXM@m@xXX2yZikzx/kr@a6voqdR0P02lS97w7vfo/Bln3xYzAP6HJnxsemYPky5lI4qDd1cYt1Rt1m97Aec5Ulxp5/JE90nzOdZylJVVp0ZZZe8aHVazF4fs83STUYDBCqEZ9nNeEcrkTkxs2Mk8YeLJsO7jrcel8Ck2wjbbruT3tKl8vmNcDnF/YslmE78TjLm7B77WI0KEXM39@lZjUbU/n4EbyI2Qtzx57cDXa1Fhko5Y0WqJrpsfJPa2kzlFwrFbDpdYmFRXDOzgMfS2audaXSDHPzDaBPUd7ekwhIiae16Te8E6AfpxH1@YTc9S3pLRD8wxSzlK3rJX7GerW@Lnq1r@BkpMD6sS@tfagF9i1J4Xa5Cbf@b1QsIEZuzNct3xq7O4mHJ40x2ZX0PUG74rFIpzgNN2QTy0S3nBwSuwHhWTpAmzihf7dnwefmgVUxaEFIhOsmcNMLww6JGrCfDC4lmgUwIGKojSOJsAnOJoY0XoTC/cAe04Pr3J@C6WkeOBpK77G6dvL7Z8azHwMEsTz1tRXdBD9@6quRj0xot@5smXQUMx9M6oNNfQ2Za7JEXmQcAWPOvZKGgPjfbN@tYCDj43N784Cn4HLc0EOF5/5Hj1DTH30Op0gqz4Hg057MSWvQ5MVdnfjFYpSBFcJZfKEHL44q7xbvxML4YwiwC3oePlOcM3gcAKuny3yW6aB18dJWhrr2Il3Xb3vp1Pnv6aIManLK@jmikpd4HnPdYqWqBQfoT8NVgJmENrPKt11@@kW02myMK2B@i1V9EUYvSllVV1uB8Oesk1dxmWOdKJIRvzCCM2eLg2izkY3/1vg99LUdWQ7eC7HT795eLknc4pb4qa@3JeuQMOiwNA4IUTP82o8lOF06p//H6zbsBzgcSPbeO2T2Ji/sXg/jDEeM0vdDq@uaHqJJX7TuBoz4FhU5kp8SwGk0QM78P6GWAXp5atwWQKs4KpNfdxrJRA5X73IquXR8OrnZYLwL/XRMTNQTz@iJ65N/CVH03p3xHG8I3nGZjhcoJiWO6hwiQqO87K18be7dKVSUS/6KyuqUtmij1xOVbYqagcJW1tqh35v4ferjdV378pyc24n850St0zig9oiGLwErdBGYId@Ut4GdlTYSmGIXxQ2XmTLLy431jfLYeG8snVRKFzT1z/@87//8V//U6joH/@LH1v84/xXWyifzxdetL6/ePVQxu/znYvlF83zF/2L5esyuOz/AA)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c)
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version)</sup>

### Explanation

cockfuck is a language based off brainfuck with the commands represented by ascii art cocks. The cocks have three parts: the balls, the shaft, and the glans.

The balls are represented by either `8` or `B`. `8` means we are manipulating the cell pointer. `B` means we are manipulating the cell value.

The shaft is made up of one or more `=`. The number of `=` indicate the number of times the command is repeated.

The glans is represented by either `>` or `D`. `>` means either move right or increment depending on the type of balls. `D` is either move left or decrement.

I/O is performed by `~` (meant to represent jizz) and `-` (meant to represent a sound). `~` is output, `-` is input.

Loops are represented by by 'chopticocks'. An loop opener (choptiballs) is `8=,`. A loop closer (choptiglans) is `` `=> ``. The shafts on these can be any length.

The interpreter starts by removing all characters that don't match `` [8=>DB\-~`,] ``. This gives

`````
D--````>>->,8,8=8>-`8------BBB8=,~==``============================================================>>->->>>->=D>-,-,B-,B-D,>--->>=D>----->````,D-=>=>>->---->>8-====-->>>>>>>8=>D=>>==88=>88-8D-----------------B=======>8=,8=>B=======>8=DB=D``=>8=>~B====>~B=D~8=>8=,BDBDBDBD=~=88>->>->=-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,-888,88,,8,88,8,>88=B8B888B888888BB,8-88-=,=,>=8------=---,-,>>-=->>->---->>>>=8-=8>~~8->888,,>~=>>8`>~-~-~-~-`=>>8
`````

removing the malformed cocks & non-significant input commands and formatting into functionally related section gives

```
8=,~`============================================================>
8=>8=>-
B=======>8=,8=>B=======>8=DB=D`=>8=>~B====>~B=D~8=>
8=,~~~~~~~~`=>
```

The first line is made of stuff from near the start of the polyglot. A loop is made to skip over the output command. The loop opener has been added after the incident tokens on the polyglot's 5th line. The loop closer is made up of the MarioLANG platform and a `>` from the next line.

The second line are some increment commands that are formed from character at the end of the long line until `-` in the gnuplot code. The `-` clears the cell to zero becuase there is no input.

The third line is the main cockfuck code. It is made by replacing the `x`s that make up the Wierd code. It is equiavelnt to the brainfuck code

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]>.++++.-.>
```

The fourth line shows a loop that is designed for skipping all the `~` at the end of the polyglot. The choptiballs is at the end of the Wierd code. The choptiglans is at the end of the second last line.

There are some new `<` added inside the Wierd to balace the new `>` for Brain-flak and perl6.

Comment: As continuing is now obviously meaningless, I have brought OP my condolences over the horrible demise of his challenge, and await stasoid's declaration of victory.

Comment: I apologize for the dishonor this answer causes this challenge

Answer (score 8):

## 186. [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 9302  bytes

*Thanks to [user56656](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/) for their advice and their help with navigating and testing the polyglot*

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        86xxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print((1/2and 9or 13<<65>>65or 68)-(0and eval('\'ppp\'.bytes.class==Array and 4or(\'_\'[0]==95and-91or-93)'))^1<<65>>62) #wWWs {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +

#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<

>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ye{--}besizeString tnd xfmain=los1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"cl91/2 <5>6#"5"8=2860ay =+ codefn( );#6and [9]=x 3 8[]p#s
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}  


 console.log 178;

#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001445 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9449 bytes)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9@api6XFL91aV1JLqVt@mWKpkMilmiczkzSQlslS66FkbvfNY2Ls9vYPeHu/c7tk1PIAX8GBtA7uYAQx4vy4G@xvufDIGhvsftM85EfniQ1J1z3hNiczIiBMnTpyIOHHixKtl@N3f/CaFH3bk9iYXPXfIhpY/ZG3PvrI8jT2bsKeG7a8XVyUJoerexahvOUO/JKWYzpjtmHYb3tnQvbQc@4PlgX@RsYHnXnhGnw27xpBZvmkMLJ@5o@FgNGRuZ360Vcb2@u57O4cx@7ZzAWBDyxt41pDC1xh77fSMfqttTIWsTyU48CDcZ7tW72P/45CZbr9vOG0fIDcYe@l6voXwpuX7LkbfZGy8Z5lTSLcA1PBs90X91edTQduMfQ4kGoOeNWZGyx96hjm0XQd5UmAnr16fHE3F0HX21en@/rRvkX2Zcx22PzIvp4NW2WvPN3rGNP41Vh8N3YPhtP86q19YjsGK2rZWnA7cYM88YybKJvMso92xe5YGBcJyrGv1BpbH0Id1XI8dAEm9rcJW4bwexdRMjLsVBSbQUi058tz2yMQSHHYtyBiWOiL1JROoqLGBqGsaOliKyOBggPrE7VtxZvjMsaw28weWaXdsk1NnjYeW40OCvsZsYN613euxttWDCBF2M8t8l438mFerZ3Q1U5Mwd5gK61/2mM3MwYDxINazgaT9whazsC6yDxDe6/psPOgz3@5D8NB0Ox3LYh@sQReiS21XYvAxB1PZCt@WLYBxrIA11gBqFbLGxUoIfAo4dO0ZA2C/L3gwtPvQZuxh2meW4dvYKiGKbzlt4uogbK8uM5w4w9iVDbUGsj7yCLdveVRuhBfK2LMApRG2GOXas4fATeRGnR1ZhsdOPctSk203kSQk5mIKQ8yIRoVaqaT3DvfTULg8hmYMoDC91dMffCEZTKuy5fMyfKuyXJb2Xu2ym@UzdPOmChVg4CmGyqrfMj9/dmbBd6y38hferQRYJeBKj@XdwTBv5AZAYG4IBOYNdKIrd1XUBr1YwqwyVRaxKseh2lAaUIPZV1nKmTnyPBRHEVONS8h0z3UugJ@QWW/kID8ctlGAIjBdkCZZZl0B16D5Uhm518Th064NheZjkcSaBReqxFAQq1CNBUeDdH23NyI4iOkPsS4DVyAqYjzosK9Yx7B7GAXCERWn2rP8UW@IcUZOG0sehKbV1lhAhum2EajvXkFyBiAlD6j6/Vi7JKIAGArCpaxi0Pf/7E/bFxeAp26artcW1fUr1nZNEv8GEQsylWGFdR2jR2QBXBZT59EhgSujZ7eNISbvTEQSRASleu2Oem3mQoLetQ2ttGtcQcuGxmUOLV7JeY@RZX3jkksTm9dcyHjfaEHBUgKUNmU7x57uQCmZlpSiOpPrj4adLZYb7LG0n3@rPCkpT5bOLCBO1dSV5Xz@ogwVTlshL3hL31VzvqonxKc/NHzXbkuDybDrOkWWM5lsVt2B5SjpBI50Nu210qqGUk5Ry3bV1Dq201bSFaiLNUg4rZbNqtmwS83yVPR4koDmGtFgc7UUU5UlEDnUKK7yfcN2tMGEfZUTrliY658jyzFYi3kjY6b9rrhHinpMrJcuVhCQQ5rfs6yBUtB0FcUEws3NNwbMy@kUDpHhkt3MpFPpTDzrhAFymsgoNtZT20Wx1Rt0sbMEpjj@AHoCD@uuaUDt8bFDGILakmUtqtfUi4BkIZl4baU9i7VAkAb1iJokb3IYP4eCUmCImlCyJVvtWEMGIQBteejPSOOeew0JEk3YzYDocDBR4wKKBiLzjNR5RnhK5JPM0qUDAgWxtSy2lWvZ0AiwuYFMF3U@ljcAXy1yGMDGG0lM9vSNCWAxebcaNRhmd6At9UE8eBNmWihzQPhYvEPBREbU/nxQ1FBlK@SK6@vJNjbTxIZevp77EQjpD/k7WxJmvp5QGqDn6VjXrGc4FyPjAnVFB6IYpmkNhkJQQU78IYii6f6GPHOi89T8rrT8dDpt6kQC1SJKA4U8Lz3RFRooXYS2mOuBMGWG0HdZ2/ZALPUm06kDwNVU4vI7BEkQ8E5eQEKgAUAls8aWORqCVIMKfN21zS7UWaTO4XKRd0LTyYNXPHWQ7LlOmDQSo9ceFyUtH3ohGQtR5LBEZ/FA54qoagkPKvy4x92YDb8/B7EbkggdQcxXyxsa1L17cPZdx52DFBgZokWQZAgvB9DETlChhI4rULuosYZaZlhEUGYgNaDlQ/3rDocDvwT9hD3sjloa1JT8qTc5GB46WFnyQ29iD13ubvXcFohlH9pnPkghb45a9ngqQ@QXluF7X7oCBazjsyr03N@MoNYp6Y4PApP8dxA4FiST4CYU/FcGQALSgFFKxydRvA9C5WTimIqsUVPSoNHJWSZjw5VVcGCskC87bh@lEHtDigFqejB2sJ0OSCsh80nkG3O7ulD2k16XTmvvXdtRbtJLS0vpUroGkn1p6Qm4Kuh6gq4MuJ6QK0cuhNPQRTGy5MLQBsVAv2b6thFgHqtNLLYx9kof7IFiNEql1WbWaOjiWcSnCqIOJBtA5/ABeNJqtYpOVZVr15BRrdVJ5n4HpfOJ6dkDwYQvjCuDvwsurBIb7P7A9VCBLWMnezdP@lUPekFQWs2u4qXPGoWz5tnNWTtzdpvOYmy1bFRbkClIT@lrF547gu5SbayVcnpTVRur0Em2qulCekVRtnI9SMhQ1c@21IzBua2kLZDaytlZGpgq@NMwux7hG2eLqhqyCujAjhl0QiWt3WxB@i21qWbSEFdNZ2GIUU2ngTMmMsGnTGPNTDDo8PhLzpidTEaiauh6l/idEfvgp8EAi0ffh/q7c/IiMdrtX4J0ZabfQ1Uk53FtBF7zK9yzTY9Q4yqxA9JYHehuIQfQ27bDkZHjOjlnRPozKbduPCEaDiIE@WHfg3LVTsAg4o49hgECtPtJoAhh/4260A4MOF0YLr8h1URm0HAYNndtrjZ0xLsVzfSjOgB6DzgHPcOEhp1EdyazM0AI9Tyfnx@ilmcQT6tKNKq5L4/QsZiGg/xr26S1j2y/i@wFzQqHEl4HuIoqO@gGFnHtgJnQ518Ap62xPeQ6PNSjE4zy3PAVFbXGOte6UNlDjQGJCmwA1J27Jox3LNAcMJQPHtmec2V7roNM1vYANVT4MpbBFPJ57IVqVK8fFHcX83cecuDYjLce420c6zRzTd9kecftuRcuWwEArJqaxiv2gWMCCaDzDWF4yXz7AzGofuHCwCdZBy3s7n3UEfWN1VD7NhAyT/Dae5A1bH6mI4AFeT45@NEe9BD6eqEA9AdvBfqEmYxhmc4jeposAhB2vx7WGyzJH1mD7sRLVCffFaNIqE@uxRsmH9cb0KECVaKFf6Co8UbOfaCdB0HtwDUv73ukIaEpIz7KSOQelEFopyI7vNlADlNT3ugbsCKBdKbAo/LdB9l52h1ZkmV2XSafgYZRrLF827rKo8CRQdB1QVXOQVKWR8pYGE3YIaWhOwKtrm317L49PCBzV89B1SXqloPQHWhgEYIj2xpKYrwRiVc0SUWy1rng8Htj7JB8yaIne3W4u3d@VD99XpXzI9/L9@wW1OC2dd4HxbNn@TKb/qTYsQXIRPwPl71j1x1WeXFd9ti9nxTGCaK/2D1/cfDsuH78NSeC0Ph2f9QzkJTS8hQARj@h4KBVxeyAHc/thxq5LwpieRVZbyUMxzg8FaFrGDoSZuOY/wb699EUrJnShWmynMtfQ08BuImAaB6mPuwik0FIMheHngJyi1CiyVjzWoHnNnqGxuKEGTVCNy98cSSB@UYv3CJy3xn5g1jObnSd/K@GnQ722qF3kbwvc1jVe5H3KnlzY3PSzCvYMhM0FzjEt0b4uJF6Lr6ZoLnAIb51jg@N2/PRTYXMAw2RbRAyNIbPxTUVMAcwxLRJmOIG9Chsi8IWWc9FWnODF0bizeEUBPALF7rNF7ZPEynx9iGF6t2ZJAc6akIZk6OQYmQrYrmr@UYuOY6IWi40rksXh0aR67yg6euIJUTRv@zNxuyAhkE/CdAZomZDuMTotzr0MwegJOwnIBxxQgC58gXagNHE44K@Z10TGI0ECRlwy3aM/DE9cEw4j57k6DZBTMvqjEAVyoOqju57wHLbWwTZabXsRaDAFyQ9eM4B80ateWyDkWl3xgDCEowfjrxhz2qL53/6cRsKYLZ4usaE1L/QcQ58o7rRWVhaIiq@0M/8kiWY96OebRAbyHUfStNAm7PRCx3zUWM/xnK5ruH1UcsShQuVE39A9N1RzzjlntUbta3gOT8RYnHSzMJjO3afcgRPHCbQoGhB9CkjEY9PinbPNdqEhavDthWVNi8Xa8wVw5i@Bb3LA@gMbDksmjwZdkfDEf/F@ZL7ytUe4Hc@V0rJSlZYN1q6lXd9o2Vbd9QDz7gctd3c4PKCMo2kbSyq7bwRoekh1@kZl9x5js75DOBZ9OyLC8sLnovArrug4ZFqmr@mxx1VJehfGWlMxl04vR7/XQQSTHuHjsV8snv08ykVkqqICa0GWYuTorkYm@wpxvaM1gRV9O6n1yxMkBQXEDxVM5MprGJ3FlrAo@nXwWBxfOwDKf729vzYfDqWs2Se4prn07A5bp6gPIuJ2XtaPfRcdt/o5YrtmHOhEA9MX5FrDiiN13Jmz/ChMg1FcVhXUHz0c1cFx87IxGoVue6o3hE5wUTIIpt6FGdgm27P9ge8xYmXRdJ02hoZocF5cfqJouLbLH/bpBL53Vzomi8QXHOIdu0F9e0BAo6blNFoH6tAmruId6Z7jd@FKkbXvbL47/xO78Ncqh4gqnI9qhm2OSd627yvuuLMKP3M5@LlXKqGZm@uf4m9dF2vazk@K2qFwIiG01JGr8dt3KcHh4vrtG/3XB8GaPh7Fy9gIOb7/Hd@bY6zzTacHFka4@750QRRA6YJy8qCwjR6F25vY@sib8DPwhIfeR3sAcTzoZIvlFy6fr/kChQk19HFc6HIv8x7l/dVBjJHejhtEXPe0d/OE1/C3L04gzCMwLnI@ZnbL2xRTC3PR8uLCsAzu9fGJHj@Fr3KIu4GvcpgQuo16H8YYXsLHEOPq9y/TWprd6fWfphMmkG7eV8mYoV72bNAQtPvTJGyYkH/xBh6ofBwCdXpjayRNVdiHLbeW7g87Q5Z8XCiCiIby8KulAfmoVUphPogBo8Pohr7b3y7U8AYPRsa@b1azlx5NwCdfIDj7SNwHKFjNuKFMxokCjfGu@ORc3w357qDoGW77QSRGPKpEmnrfl0qobb7Fn0Xqfh7fReGyG4fdAbnAeUvkJIpjv8mEJNPhPm9jTZO7068JRbOb4JeC/oHlKp96efQUPowwVNcNLYn4O1tGL051nCCv4u4PU@Qtly39ymlA/K0baNaBsomrjW8r5RmdB0x1c0iK4aPFpFWZ5H9gvc1YqAJ3MNB9cKCPoIsDalzeEgpz9ha7@i1YpbX@8ab0GOTkcj3zMC9iN5jbNy6tqVt3kkwV0fdltUz@GO8sXYXvm1t9SEq0SDQc8lSj9Z9bs@PJkRSUyJoMAFm2W0Yq3StvkWvdyj5Rvv9yA8eC4HGLn7nBGt5sk4viDewoc07@JuYO4hpRUPXgdHV0PAuLBye9HBSS/gukrOB0Xsucw/6xoW1f2/liqwUuA6KD@oi53x7RYkvTTAh2j2ShI/8XOfSmvjBc75@PDGhPEf9O7HNa@cmGkPvbdhafq6t/x61z@m6XadrdT1qHOHbouYBNXLI16bflQmgv2v4l7jwi2RSNKzr@nHu9txe7yHcRZnIJaTrzrfT7uGi7TZE/SS8E6MFAeJxr0kPum5iEvXhi9pO1xpBD@W7Q3dg5ehtEWgPjT/8d77p@eAw7bM3tuW1@aw1WgKNod3qWezaBhLe@/Gp0vmGpVbPNXBt4R1KPHAmeD7EVGW63r12kAvDHQ4G9Dgf9EY@/ZDJN9eZb8sssX2i9CGVwR7yBQO8yloXbsvs2veR1LKMoWNf5gObDn@dX82TwphybrPcLnprPRt45U00rATVePgJPg7mN3z7hdhacqdCsjPyvMn9wiE5FRyaX/mkAToWGWDErN2cYOr6cVVMsPrjjpkLMcm3sEaRMo2Kc84qgHaiLzQHJRYACRb0VleH93DJdM3Le/WJhYZMMT9MJj07NscN/tNWjLvJeC7kG4wOleejC1@9v@J226BX4c/cSlK/4BUEJ5b8nnsdMzxD0zcc8Zgbt/ji/tRpdmT9zomSEtNfnNcPD@5HZvbsgc9/Wa5TnKsqzM7tzkJN5o99RVG1rQ7/vU@/67seroMGRSJnepZvoh0cZTCXjVzwOO4FyOJcj0XAAexc8menkudpKMl@LvfDV9aFgeuiXti4RKrnz3Z9gHl6VvkhiH8wMnz7ByN3aM3FOT27/BCUL40L23yeKIEAYcBdsYiGPxLCEr1mC@K6a/u0HDVwLNIjoKLdLQ6nDe7h5qi7jSMxHUmsDWS5AxasIQwdaPLHcGNuWnH13R1MHtQlkS1VPOfWp/lz8ndZF65H/cHIF4/5KnAfl5nHTcr9S/L3r20Q0blvQACzrtEbzjU783n/Y9p@FC5U97NifRX42Z7YJeNrwVa0FK1Fo2XrwTJmlsLF9COUq0PX0xjBKYqRyaiqxCOhifrCAbAAijYD4UYBvs/IZz3bHxKs3WGNBlu@GZcKJf2WVZlcklmzybHih5at740HtJPnmEdvLBvN6nI6l0svp8@cEiukQ3CrB@UxF9xIwHZsenB6IxYwx@ArDtEd5LjMN0L4XdpkBLpIG3Sa1zAUpn7N9fhyfr5X5BTnxv/jX7TF3isY@Pisb4NkBIbg1kO3b3Xd6yc8XZF6fTAwcO8W4oCG1OM7CXI7dQblCsoP33LlXrPX@6dbYiOH2OcIL0fYS8eo4IWLo3BchjnkhcepCZfUiYTDWEGmTLc36jugbraHXV9jJzatsBx50VIpcCGYM/RQ525n2QFrWzgDSQtnaZjZc91LWgGPlPzHv@DbV2j5rFjWGCRP29ZiKeIqWZ32jJimOwKqAyQfLM8VIAoyGRrTCI040DAt7q/iolLaVwM1MhfsKqFk@NaSnfoJy@2xNG7hxMXqZbujLNePP/@qUWhWv2X9vPWffpxXbwTj5M9y2xu@nGUBSPkWK1Y8eB2Co9A0k5fHMk8wXFtsC93mmpcHsMjglQyXFwd1zHUHotXQzkDaCBfWRrHNWUE3lXOwvaRPmwqpwlrXtL2E1vQ5KGRwt57jQwODV5VQ81ZXXVZG3M6QOxmydUgQt@gY4OLbEGm1LW6VwCjLY/aRdbGS5UxcAQpvnJE93J3Trz4LlqSsxhcO5Xet1ohmy6@KWnG1StlZPq9WauTyrLaLu@Qab8/GxULubLy518z7AVPPzsafFYo/BK67MARafpzHlrf3avdmWasVPn70jQmT5dt0ma@NAjGxfHN0cLR3clo/fX0CpXAbiJ991@sbkazBWkRrOrtuj/YfAl882/I/Qf6EbwCuKGzZYBXcnq2qUny5IoEKXss5eZk7Y6IpEfue6PPi@1YsfBZAyLSOzYIadQBdGJYhVDbkGmZ@NMBdlEzEFTvBqJbZKOOxAYWMwRVoc2QpsUpmVWBWDpj1QFaxxZl9wv0ewrF7sdzNtidzQZBjYXqNMJxncS4Lbv9e8j2AjvJ3zzfHcne@CeaOfANo6BvE2a8fvHh9vJeMBnWMniR1q9vrYp0uF87Y0riJItj6RlsaRES00VRlJlME/io6sxFuimpZw2sLsiWEo9nnkamGEv2yFFVM4EwVDzBoljkvFIUoQB2kjNmaWkbcsccxEoM@OobuhmcxFAL7cog6IFyTBeYUnQOg4SfIBmIV7Aqa3hEJcSGv035c/ckGLQ6zhn00qHsUa0FXFfY6PoP/WK8UuIpNNmaiO9ObLMeK8O1ZMOjphrBqmfdRbJkzQl7mtMshvbgHHWhqvzdokESLmcRKaeile8YAN7wK6FcwMCmxb0YubcsIhEmoX1yj8m3w4xaoaE0Dc0PbPZwhbl4N@i3Cd7B/UkXtjKtmJN/jdW7kYEcFQLHDD/bGoFNDZeuQrOfbqDnLXbFjN@gqyXbmix16oZbgsyvbJ9saFkIHdZweSErMjcg4Hl9BG3JYveeDTtKG7hs0lCF2taCcaLRGly/UzTlMTkGd1EKVMctkCWH96uwOTuhKr03oVt/xyMsER5h9ac5W8zMr//0/@1O@vfxsCO4/EO5x4Rm8/ZF464D7nwYhug5v/zx8K8LbT/nb2zxydHZPLc9NyERk4FcHR8wn8x@yqG@MY7nHhotFaTsjKNY@8PqKWIfgPFsRZyI8SuMr4DwUF7AdtQZUFCg9y2squCOylM@jUo1zNhqtHbXG3PZHGyS/GeHBAKDb5DfWN9b0PBCZuwoQ0i6lC1ysyBGqaglEjXRlD6rvWiarVCpM9k2jZ1U3ypzl@WXj7ar8LiR0GWAlrn83GMSBKFEMCKuJaMqykdFVjIr9Q1pPo6hou7wEQclSyAEgKno7wTYP0OJcwSqoHo41HpIiMgnGFSAHHdo4YPHjIQJEOUDEceP29elaHi0/xNXasXqvxYtBfoNgJwhWkudVssZbdjY8c5riGAMGFeaXc6qcA@4/nHO2QVh76rOb6pXpLfGYG/b0xHFxmeo@UMuUYr64mtc31FibkgUqoBdb0EdACW0G2qBp2e/dgV/f2Tv44vDoZGZzOEGmp8HSLF2rZM5yWrbRDB3pqVofMPXZfv7k5bP9gJVxqqLZW4SIpnCnyZyX2jSlC1J/w9d9zqZNATMJ6YWHIqa5ktw@rXKYxR6F5mOAO3y92Uyqinpz22hWamdOaib5j/MOzEhpK1i5wHXm03EZaTZH5hwEq1lP8TQnXws2QhTl6DiYcNsDf4@8F2/vDs@GivZ4B@tmJdp9FW6@krQFK2oh71qeJ0UbnDlhAb0gawJSdSQ1StCUZmbg49QwkZfZY6zEDpGQSYfcNEPnVhgOjMY92@TQPglobsChwxZg6H4Q643NLq26oQHnhAbwICpCu3fbJtOU4QXbfsKQE6tv504DelBwRHu2xWblLuStZ7fKRrUxZuGmkbu2Lmv@oGcPFdxHPdbQMAK5UVTMgF7BjchjtbLdFHu@WbA1O0O7u49GwK8jd8Aio9SuFbiOQUVhuyNAbuL45otRH@A69Di2sJewQGnJQWTgYzogooH7mUUetH57HVLXuta4bV9AT6OoWRBJn@l6tC/cwI3NThrkMGfV57gsMc6YT9rLHuOY0TA022lbYwW3DZaayB3wT1@/uUqr8kwdoA31Yvt0e3pnfSAsjKFotdGu9CmBsL0dCoJk29ne1rq@hJt6QBmGFE@G3gtwQh@qdPrGgCkjOprAZxqjV@VMcbL@0FNZrob92TVzWCZDY2l4UADoygjaIZdNe0AVPMlHyVehnNHXd9r4@GAPWEPXtCa4KRGVLaMdbQfUDbRAqRKMjSBKidBCBwx/JaQIlM42UsSfy5SsRLuDAWpuMDXkiy41QOAF5ZrVHkdbMWMtkHN1e7skSiMpDrcZVIvKHIkBaOeIuUA3Bf6KbRnANRRiALXjWW0bBMrTLy3HgfaqQJ3pQ@tkxggqmadmg2P0stEJRZRCipP4XOzzAEKTJxftpW96Lugzy/kymWTKt9DvvzvDjr8juv5J/r/Oa/nyjbLcq07yoIypNWW5W9UzqyuZzLKzoiw7qI48foyWnNtl0HbONRgYjQEot9xTy1CfQTuqLjvlZaOiLLerxRWKAa8wNLuBCN/6ee1m2bjNLz8GbSILPh5vncqyT4cKFDRNvwX6sIUs57NQZ25wdzwdjofJL9uZDNKgLZ8jAd/mz04y1K@cneTJaFQWSm7@oh@IkaSuEpbEzKF@nIHCuxRK9HWU6GKNznkAHJ1btDov7E7t@ktc0cho8tXy/Xj9SoY8XLAIgYbCSQgZhZ/qAAwcK8BEfM0aqgrC5De/SekbjMlPNlYVN/NkvVDOpNd1GB7CuC71FBTV/IrsyTdnu7krZuXSjY6xrn3TPLo8OvqheqawbZZO7RzK@pr8lm0X2cM@m6y44MN@l08qtZKXUvkV/fFmPv/u3TtQyeHTqGk1EB/8ozZy6WZD2WSstrm5kt3YWsk@TZ/HCFOVYlE9YXl2Ztv2wG@34et26SRLJcU/T55QWjDshH/G/UT6whG8IIjwTX0qnLGeYmebhrGSWSs@dcpA2jZ@VpkOTvzdgq/O1tfZHn7@5n/7m5//zc/o7@f0/SuDXbIP8LnsMPwn94d2zG2gu9X5gIcugO5dJbkwSKfXV9Mnb9Ps/7PPEtNrTzb/888Ov0kNU7Vi/o0Hz2Hqm9TGVoo7wQFvq8HbVaqWqiDYxm1qkq9Wq@Dc/M//C8SvfQF4MGRSgZ/aeoBrY5Kq5aoU5WOqtgEOvViEdP@vH/9YStXGqQ8pXddTE/o7TxV0/Gw91h8zBo68vLklu@7TgN6tjXH4Cfzyul48i8ozVtxYtKF3F9KBcmVuKglK7rBWMVEbyPEpcHjW6cbS03e7jFnQ1eKnVHo6w/AXU@/HWg4@mmgGY3zJjYMspLaq2XOefFhXUzHHVIbDXybyHr5/IpyUCs6KyzWMTpONY5@zlL61dvh0/OAPi4gOmJiKeBcmzqb9Aq6HLyxo9OxT4KTUt9Xq8RD/Xrbw7@gE/35bMceewGcJ/ugfPuEr/i6Rj/AmkNnP0u/QXKVUI9VoNn/QpT8P/547@Nf6Bv9efMC/Hwzx79TEv@Mf4N@izEipSqWSymSOQTUUdfYhn9fw1bRz8RbUXUT39/pha4cbh08llso1M7nb24b2dpwpl8U/KE3l8A0/3AVkNW9zucrbWibTIPIaNUFnJdesAa2cZPp5WwHEmUqjUtHOa7Varvm21qgkI4l4T59msJ0@hYi1ZqMhpW6wLKr4s4I/po@/RVnO0yt2FtA7b4OLkZMewoPRWcP4LqXeVd4pmSeZJ4Ve4aqgX@qXL93D6P/wcAwB9rjw3vUK3UJXb4NEZAXrdWFSmIwLffdQb4PTgr9CH5x2oTMuXBScgqPrk3EC1eL//qE7fHnoAjYXYg7HhSEiLnTgeXF4@BLwdSDt9/BnFwqFMRA5LlzBf6GHgppOoKHn23P1TGow@Z0Fvb@mp7VCWttIp@3m@sbgm7Ob2@LGN3I2fX7WSDfLqbx/dpbn2hErrpXp/KHb2/PzvVe75@d5rEeV5czTTO4pfKq1TEU8nqRq5SdnpRyWH69/2nkqX3lyVlvNoXsjA4VUBL9KPvOJnwglPGtLZxIM@N68we@b66tr7iIHuc7evAlD8SePXuQiL/gAaH5u/ISDgab5D/TfPvz/1//L10xpNFXGlJvbikIfFf9U9eb25lb81lRFES9KBf7QA94xys1tDZ0EdAOuhqI21dtb7ge/ilrhCGuYRqVGkSNAaLApnupZugwaXnVZEZM5Z2fjQkEtt8AntD8bH2leQC3TionlFs7lwGhAX1EJZH2tXF4T7s2tcnlLuPWNjXJ5JYQqwItwApDlG2YZK3o5pSIJfGyg6Pkimly2YcClr1YqG@u12sY6vGxsqTmlgEF0AFz6LD0YDM7SGtmfNdrSVK3WPc@YkM1pDcZ7Z9C80riKorq9joddbuuul9teVdOq@lYXqIsqS0HN89nNbYo4wNbWVaU1sVS2tqFsZbbFX3VJZZV8bYWJv0ZjNbO2srnytNmMunZsqOUbo6rfVm@MEg7Tb8umOOSs514w4/Hj1e2PH/WtQvlMOj/frZ/Wz/G0aFlGKThgDH2pzUs4rzTw0g0yqqxvNxvIqeZZOl0qP@W83VpnqXRZwOXSID3Y1jYxNAUjN7uDqxXHKFzFt6SvFFeX8uvjzzb2CqDpflzBT6PR2CpuZVZAuqxsbzebTfL9uERxGv1xp0knqFRzDX1jvZlDFeL9uLMCxOqbq6kVaUCrSDYLrI0TcR5zO50l8OwaPmvhnKlv9XrBwXLXrtdrX9ttC7Afvajv7J1mixVAWdyv72SLJ6@fpXR8XY/eKXgV34/36ruHryHC0Yu9@sne5wdf7b0@An8fOipgFnz6R4Y1ss6t69HoGt/PLfrs2L7x/r0xGJxDfRmMO9//8iff//K//f5XP/3@Vz/5/lc///V3P/8JfP8Cvj/lz5/@2@11/P31d//8f/z@z34Fnn8F3/8A33//6@/@5Y/5l97/Gr7/R8zvr8U3Bse/wErA9ke//u5nf/7r7/7pL@D7r8T3F9Pf7//k3/H//1P8ofNX3//JX@OPePnJTwHh3/3lL/H/Z3/5d//hl/j/P/3rv/vLf/F3f/RvyPGn3PF//6t/y3//9vd@8rf/@I//9ve@W/D7kzt/v3uA/3f/AD4Pp/MheB6Sr0/1@e63oud34UaUClWqn//h9//y96G2/gl/@yfwBv9h0B@EL2FIhoZUuUzk@QeMfcyD0lJ4@jEEBZT/A/qCN/uYxEa@hcD319/98Z@jdwL29@MYCvos7DICh6n9AcD@WUhYHPYPvv/lj7//8//m@1/@6fe//CMUYrm17Ww9m9PvGZUA4PoD4BBw4yFwAAgdRqXCltiSVATHUgWNBZKeefcOWLoELlB@V6T1VXiT9Bq5dXRDRBhLrPDRbAbH6PAdS2vb8AYO8BqTA4IyEPQsw6rVakYaVyGMQOEV44xZbQvHnaivVwEvRuJxsudboAuy8TPCAjGrmWN2vlId84gZ9KgRBoYEodexrBflzFZ1FxKsjncZ4kLkGekdPN9Va1vVcQ3RfUskAI7MM0gSoKpI3bj2LbxXCSfAS@Pdb4GUrWomU9sCnypllVLLnlOa@jpljvKeYZRv9GcMrVdPnjL2maxvyXzcBKxkAhp/MxH0E7IePIHws8yKyA79B076rmB8KKcx8Yf78fAn6E3xBQDgzeVwrQx8czmk5ikEjzmqDCULjwzHAJzLCDNL6EE9a0bKUPlm6AXSBxoe9qnUYi@IDrOzvLwMrkpNXpUPQQFn3mXJHxoemvRJQyoxeWNbRm9cjmQtH5GKvrK7Ar86/O8t0fJBzo4VaTmN3XeaBWnkMqvumpsi6oOsUV5WiPIMwUmpyJ@rhTQvA/rcGlMlhU5HVWmcZw1Aa5Fe@hfP3DFTCllZzuob29y8KYaBX7ulUvVbfW1Tgie9j/BgVnFEKBQDXtahYetChtZuchVqaeAEFWNDqtXE3BLTpdrJ3ilEOD1kerGgMVDtbtY2i2vra@vF1Y2N9c2ivraxvbaxvrUKEmqjsF4s6ttra9tb25u3QNBTaOfZ0kprvVL7RzOf/@ofzfvM98WPVPshG2vs6OgHuVupNs7l8kUiuaqvb5YnVSCEvKQaaU98ZDe5yfk@w@KRzlrWhe3c4JISIE26yWFVfQQfJj2S2CPwgg9gRss6EzOaB4dlMe@Fx17zuS9ZX4fKoEpnUBk4NmkQ/0hYcI9B2jzWuXN9I3IW0Cmd4sr9V5AAlIPDXuDCtqHLTl2@gOqZZS6A2OnyK152PBf0zd8e5pnhXPKgXRsPCDOHYdBzA4//8Pv2sLsA4vWgj5shLO8fDMNevwUEovGPAzyDH6/nuvMANtnrowW5fBnu9cFpNNrsA@DHB58/P409T/fqO8@lDfbs8NXu1GNdAK2zF3v7p@HrJg8Noq6HKL7ee/Fi@lU8cMywxNY3s1kQfPCDzyx96Kktvw1AdG1xj2hphayePZ9YN7ncbcvCw4BP@HHHQxBM4w5V/J7r6@n0hdWHjgyaqg61GRdRXrg9GCUtF3YKaPDPf8RRzrlVXJ@wZZB7Zm8bRoGssl7bSMnr8la1uLVRgHFdNUNnMncchanl1AYO8xrbzeqYrbKtRnOQ8qWXuEZpW@dL2G1feg5jkz6eR4vbVoeSZ7VhnHLt0Or8Ft79MBqwhZ7wQC90evZFFwTgtRsC@FCfW4bB4PupH8BhxT/Duz2GPA3ymwnpzYJL16GlJjTBsNAWw6XCG1w@SltHgvle6mP8knSK0phuBGG4JbKFh2jTTiPo5vmmQDry2gLZvC1JOMdld1hB0shyVdzeWt/aXi1uZbe2t9bWYcS4ntWLWX1za3MbKktB39I3tta39ezW2vbqGkhmCF3f3pRSIL3sTj4PHY8uy/S0HROPK6zguY@u1q1JKSh4bEtsjHcopYzQY7TF5NWtswKDiLKEyyhXxlW5uIZrnFd1psuSbDCTpfb3dwr7@7L8DF/QTLdTkOU2vqxvFQqbz2TZopAd6D2KEKmLb3sbqMDKso0vO/X9fcTwHl@KW4hDli95CH/pBS@bAObgy@oqacCy/E2IrgDIXU7RFsUa8pdC4dmOLI84ebg/C@Dq/G2NiN3DFwzASPs8ZAfCZPnzIFIB2CAfcziR1PMgv/W6LB/wl3odUXxBmV/nmfoSX@r0gUgevEHFl@ULcFx4MJKX5RY4sfrLsgkuc2KAXx9cePSBMzRkecLzgTmR5TFBG@alDIqd8Id0gJ7nz43usG1d8M/E408Tgg4gyB6P9vZbn3/eurhoeZP63ufHFPTFF8@N95OR17poiYitc/i4GAuCLvuT6Y@FQefnRm9@0JcQ5EwFnU/OLaLw3PgGKBOfC0yof/4FBn0BQfMmdQRC@PQBuIWfZ314PjNaPCj4UBA9x62WXMYqi02no1DFNbL0aDH1BkWiYjwBTX1NLqFwdTugX4221Nz6k9GWvLEpl1bgKT@RV8E5VgrpAmNy@kyWVRCKT@TNdbmUfvIkl36sP2Hy5rZckjc3ZbV8i3JZUW86yjg7rhbAI5@vYDvGlgdPUFmEvnFqjYfacwsXVJi53JvEp1J5A3C4DRH3Yb0a9dkzdk2iA1dlBytoz6vPQE4Uyg7uRbXwdXmcGku1tjE0YOTx7GZUKgnY2/JFtYEIPuJPJSe/qb2Rmyye7vpmAah67ZjFzUql8bEJaldVL09S0JMUt8pjfG6uxRWu5Z7hD5f1zWKpMVpu5PTm0lLh40VF/lGNMKPiRX9xEx3IqjL4Bdzg0i3Vsd9BOCvl@Knp@taGquF2gHO3c04nI7N3MSGGEQdVUWYyU/BaA77eQ0mnN4vptJouA/ASeIvCoMIOSksGQQmltV0Exa7sWcMRqBGF8m1AS5gMVyo3dCl1K7XxuMO1bSl1I93e3FZqQS/9JZtMjEwueH3M2EUGxhd5Mu/jxMASuXJa7SmrV@sXx/WyAK3v0CgAKsQZ376Syy996iRCplJ7y59nNZxUg3QkIp9PtOUrmVq@VqudSbIsp@TQBry1DmMHHGB/myK7Ltu56YwcWgtYeokMM0pc02g01W9f2b2brdVcjdavKFCdb1OZSh5np7RanrhlHtLcrZRyXOFEa@QQarcC6vO6jAMViw1Ott9uvt16@/L14evDffa0UNoqbXFW0GT602xWT@tpYO1T6LTs4z0pNfjoruvfOl@UU6VBenUtvZpQkM6qYvemgjVBaaDNvLHabDZgENJU4a1aLT7R17cyayV9U03VcBdZcTNVIwe0mtxqqpniCNY2mQovZPct6qlaXvjrm7qa8nP8DeKsgwqU2nr57iMMIMW1a3aRXPm8oGr5tnIL/7XbBoyxbmmodUv/@JOHn1sOAP8IHr7wR/SJwcVhovDmt7kK/6/Qz84hp1neAI6n3lVrULBvz9@ep6TUdrqWyadZcT1gnRi8oDqz4tCf5a/g39vIYwU0sJXwDV4rK2y9BmN7ayWfz5@pPyiCOrK9vbG1kZJ@A9m/YyUvhIZL2zoWDBdAnM1Z21b37JcGrvtzwvVt4Hg5@oAXXjwNbsoLNBeGqgsu3kTdJe4n1JmYF10wmfSb@HncfoO@koQum25uZR2qSyiwhrRjhK2g@MGtwap0Iz0CXCNzSDt34KcsSY9wuxa@KgFclj32hyruDyio0qNHQr74Q80fniNyjCQ8c3pZupWQPUa77TO6cganW/h@YgP3nrgDfuBXb8J4JJ9uBeFqWHhwfIzgFdbhVEBuVhilSJRj5njyjzhYa9RBUvYPXuxBHBj0dmiVmYgtey28z4myt9RRWSgmgQd4K0lVcIrAERDQgSfvZdU@blo2qV2yDNMxvEOr1QAqy/QsUZJlHRGxga9NiI7oOyaMaQAxT13hOWAr5yJZkQdBD2UCWIi5I1FP94V4F2ZWlB4emo2zgDfBji8FQ1mFFdXYrjfCBYXB72CliGa/LS6XqUZsJmx6MwtFW@Zb25QQTvhEjLqVVobZfpkX1aAsfamYoBW4nlL@tv/4sfl20Og3y2q/OsRnJtOHHuhSsTnIyrDar0L1GDTsZnnYyGTsZrWvfqngO14Bhd2VUGl8VeQNcu5UgRZc/eer2Q8NJ/et08zuN5wMkDzKrvyo@iFrVAuolWTtqp7tZb@B/p3nA9IcVj9knLJRgS@u2EzsOoTeNmOUE14Y5VLpVT80jCaqOT2ImMnsQ2aATr/Ry2SaKiTeg8DZiOXe48dGplcbl3u5nIpQb1ef7DeG4GhmqvheUozK@MmHxgjilxR4ViGZngrEQzzB69uQdqCvDDzmZRqRzmkkLWwM5PWr1ZUfPVn50Up1aelDY5zrN7Oc/aVCVBuQ@DESX47t61RWfqSyKZbQbK4if2aXPtNWcHOenckAk7ODWExO4cqPIGSQyQRU36K8PI2PDrGGiY1gfNsdHcdPE62kEdG4kN8/g@Ki7pu2LcD5rvyBjXvM8SibLF3cZBAEhomrajHwbPzkiRQkLfYeQcooXGAcauBonC4sxK2cdF4B46f23Cdf54nhQOaGw0i6RAgGrKsbseZKookanO@ZDQRBMXBTuC1zicV3nIGwIekBMCQ9EC6HUgSZJOSEgKyKQCitoIAgFsqJDj9xig7dQfmEt26FLR9ECCcDGvMcMuzs@yrJJqhPNriYXaH0wAFNRXoEmUAaMA92k9VAkLHHj5l4rVSZXtzEvgDBEO59RkegGUoh8QdQCjiQyvdQR1EeUiJA2yMMwe28iYTWfreExA59BSJk3mf5Rn2NNuorI8fnB1sg31ROBpbFo0fvM9U1QRD8k@oN8SHs9jcp0d2X2M7hy6PXp3vHL@sn8AuDsK343WzBtakzlyYO8DLElu3QrkDTONatr78wGVNwJIJn6@OtyG32xesXrFh8tZvFE2@B9SluDIcOtRRisny6ecTXXO8if21f2vnkvfF4gS1tQKRb6nPBJW4WbZqni5DD4zai0zZ8tIxBZy6O6UxccNW3fF/cBZkL7tWmM9Lo4JE@np8BrVDcHUl7OxJbqXEdQJa22Hj2hU2XJXc5gkR8ugRqyKNT@5DwzkcaEEKNlra3CoUSK2TRoQeOYuBYDRxrgWM9cGwEjs3AsRU4toVDDzDrHDOMGldXNyLnZuTcipzboXOtEDkjDGvFyLkaOdci53rkjFJbC1Pb2CK8LBVwk5qu5WGYvrYVhNFYe0ie64BGn/ZcA0KLM5AQfW3GE9LbSnpubhdEQgf5QwQqFjeid5A@AWxV4VRlOR1ZnjJ/E57QV0l82EYVds/zQCrtjfGSW6h0aonhjnlJwuUpZs8yQBmwhqClVPeh/ltqifqgoTcpRccFIIaqHr5DdLwiDOLodE8zrz5zgovzgjm24lxs/GwlFjImdnCCIJJTWUr0tBzjWsIvjnUJBSxydAFEkUNgGSTPWQjSPPVGc5NcvTvJBMK5Sc4QxfGuz4uFvFEIeTWISv0/YasG6XE9xaLSBjUAY0KhUx2YKlA8Z6l6o5fkX3/3i/@Z/fq7n/2Kff9nv/p//v1/j@5/hz//Kx4oUAwBfvozRmsK4OdfMFoxQOseokgEv1qSv//FL@H1v/s37Puf/IwH/fGfy9m1EBGEoFcU8@f/BH9@H3/@dzm7HgL@/A85IEaRs7dSQrVSAOqnf8UYpIZYQmS/@AvG5AwoGIqoeQ3expuxM1U4gpANDXI1p8P5L95tCjwuqBkZ8Io3PXrLYAGoMeSegQd/RW0P1Bluz0MpbRpmF88pEF6uj/qPiSqM62sXUN@u26D0CPNCGnL/e6zE0hmEQTMJHitV5TJc5F/kW45CETYj54E6vN5PoKKbX0NKYHgrQf2mkcDE13DYQiNSndcRwd9XFnQTQQciBzWLbrKURFpBbLStiEvB6WrTYKiLlRa7IX4sE80eSWIjvR5LMCFupooNUpn2gSFjdMJKPCp5WP0BnhBSjfiNjMUX4kJ2Gl1UcqLZ7B3uTzUY/LRAxbyMS6QwoSqT5XtgkdMCXkWNazUJz@kVAI1CabWZOKtlHrD8wx/@UJZifgWsQ15bIQyxTHGREQbpyaBiLKgYC7I7AifJmvVicYoG6jhQLiYPKuLRYiIqGS2qXNhygnJAMmAsiBcCy3K20xv53eosapLISWE3izyGUm9WRTs5c0jm1JiszkQAnMk41emynI@6MAMzW1DzYyK3Ez6J0lqMKREn1iiIe9I0l8KS07fnlVwywTtQ683MAxMqFn7HhHIPTGhj/f6EposV4ybQL@bv/WInEBOhhI@Q8YafSnRQ2DX@AqpeJI6QYo@cigpDnroY8rSuXabMuf0d/PPBEfeJK9@92MH3OIjBo3e4eeDpwIUhh4tacDBUMhz2WoAnhh38Ut0Lx/UsP34Ijrhn10nj2USme@FAr5bFo/btS0vctmyJ4y@T/UrYswktFA8zhqEPouaMQs3z/Nx27OH5OSifvY4aMRBfNRP3bqclEyKCKxZfCVXbw4Hi4pUhQ/V@nKTv8mintnmpHA5EYBoSqTMY0JlWDwZfrItXUwf3DGMW@WXVoJG2hgod69t1@@6F5bh4LBPGnkJ/EOFGgozBgGjJMiPLzBhFYhCtmFlDFVG//OSo7Msi3s0exC8mESSYkWXeNI@Rs96c5M4XJsejBemdfDq9J3F6T@6mt2N7/nCaZvJEaw8@Py3pVSXCAIARGav3k5EVpyDOkJMgJfT2US@iCA8msU0LktpIaR1A6wJc60D9yIZvPu3SFoR/tYj/dxdgEH3vocVHyuzJBORNn24xpyGaH8w8KwB@oKrhesV4cmHV3n1gWmKgQyO8LJNJcDl4BAA0zMHAcqJrpAPE99R5XDQ0U@9pJVGVB86hybvKssvi4iLaPW9bPWNitRUBmY3hDXJ8bBltklcPyzgKOhJ6MAYgQ2YhqydUMTqqhYBKC6qMkb1S1cXVioPYYe2hyTii8GAx/8hwNy2a0Qha5XMgrgcSNEXHi9JpsIPJYMKPd@rRuWuBHOX9Dy/JV6442O1OhgAfxER/NkpWvUt8Hithlh7QI4SwWjLLdEhC0G25oI3PlOGnsej@nJKVIYxUDUo5oZ0sKnH7rhKP1YqgTnKt5GFV8r5K9@A6F6tqHFkkwnY@rQuZwbxj9HqmqcQxcp87S8x1ZmQC@mGJuc6CXuV8jkANY5KkG@JVqFWuX6iSDc4DeF7B8yt4IkIYg57zChXkDfXawORFIX1jENNahE/DRF00xkU1Po8Yg5ICNxpyb8M0zYVpmjNpmok0wxaQTDIGJJmJJEUpYPHcVQQ9qzNcIJ0xCEfu8LhLbMPHcQ0P515v0na6ZGdZ@ipdAoGcttKlPQWEcrqdLu2Sw0@XTshxmS59CY6obaU/pktBs0AAD17J8RT9hQjHdzNd2lHUW2mIZysH6WrpUlimAPOEvxJHbrl5tSVm/d3QqmpZWa5UZhnWGB8eLmar0czStwD//BBVftg3BC5VWXGFgHEAkug0Yj0GTwe6Da3nXlueMq/7KAWmKWHfiGwoEJ6pxowqWEtGJI/SqXRSGHHCMJSMj/AEAlFuluZTxPSZkdl95IjUoYZSISfTJ@5ppA@0FQpvAHDciNOL4gfllUTBC/BhdGLkRXTOkBMkRxThYgB1DlnI1HfpOzKFZT11/DMv/XgJzdoIsBBzAQgvJUIbk@mgw6FuSokN3EGyklAozvbZ8Tj4EY0Sa@9UNJIKomUuCCZvkTMUDPHGr96VnVg8JC0hgjCwUWjyVhb2CySLMSiSdTFNlTc@ICEmc9p0/p2F1XZXOAmOi5ss9RWLuqEgLk@SJFdSTEJkDbdKj4whTz2al8EN1J82fA1ijvE2EQURxGKGqXD56n6C/u5y/T1QqAMmTCUwT7Ge35XOqtd39rJTlPeiZGcLEAOzbFedqxyFKUQsh9FBTDO/q67NqPgjJ1DyeaIh9iltP2BbOCa4h2/TYwuOC7UE7yrpeYmG2cviYkbNaiS9Ky1QWjRMSeDhGQ8pjbJ2N6084/OKGEOwj4bHJxewlyzgeOEhPsqAN8Vy3spxyxXNU4Rtm04xi2Yu@KyDi6vEwpPLY54g7mn9WrhECzwOz493D1@9@Bo63c3NTXV2KgJbLcSN@nHpzmmCcNhSzOL5n7hnjtZOdF1vuHTmyLNLysgDlAGD5m149RNtXBWyLCbPp9ouxOOwMY4KXJdRMzASUglVHQO7bFvwlV/BqKwYAkmg3gK/szRaw1kjrB04oXN@Tt3X@Tkuzjk/F70YFk04jfSbFBNn30mp5Bom0rP8maP1cNg/6tO2pcDsJg7N46tP8CCrg2EQO4w1coZ2sMQBrUK0JzKYwVdWdbRJHHRCH6IDl2IoxTUcuBbXVXxQLIRGcyctqBTpLHH1Bm9B8QeuQ6d/04mqpKzjnSx@YHAlskfOtUGLP3gqdExGjCK@DCuYDXMdfkGJz@PiZkwyHAe8yTLrQqN5nuI2DDQu7QE/FDpc8OGrFIkIppVZwONWz@oDSSdQY@fYkF/aUGm6@/bFBVSfvLhNlC9rOTUgas7t5HaCww5T7CujZ4e3P4iVYHR5i7D@AjuVxGmVPitugA61nQXORl9gLC6OYXgiZYGWZhEUfDfhscmdW9lY3CVlos4@V/Ul5RxL9CPvFzy8MfTKcGL8pc/HuCFaTFFSq4/NUwJzHXHIXRpPuQsPSpTEiblVmqbUcInaQJFTcnCCIjqlgWehuM7pfP2E0TODox0VPFS0JD1ySALhUjBm8kU2oOk6qL3RPJsark112GdstSjRTTYuWZk5AYCDT/ElsEMYRMV88GV@QtLIn7Xlz3BWUXqUQqHIqx/GD2o3uum2gqh6syWBDte7iilM3iyCl/XYC7YOfvcMZB1HIxtA4RxKlhQ5A2gzsipz1GH86ehimuQRF9GzmLI4U/dIsBqw/OaT129bnucQmHTlQkWmW@TF2uPyHauBaTkwrjlMLAZGouOrOzti0Ru/eTErv8ZlWyWeCHU4Gh6ri/K@PC3wc3qwxpMeuLiardCW4k6id5I9jBySsWQ7dxFA3RBVdBRTtGbsM78EX6AhG6AENtEyB4V4o95LG3EEF1/TmVrNcqwfUvQ4NUhgxwd51AF@ZmW6h@IxRKR@GTpJdZ6uVSgn4gNx/sCh5d9yTpMpqliqjJiSKHhpon@4YFaiVfKB3LvjogAjr28VNrZp0TVzssNsv7HdzK6YVZlZQ9tw@v7Iu25fXrjdK9Aw2OB9a2xOPnzD2Poaw@0lxcf89AF9o4o7OhS2iYdAsu0C7e0QBD6hkxTOZMZo@y4em5BmLNwEVF7CzfvwyeJPSS7P1FK20g9qIV953W9sNKtOtVDuN5xm2clk1GGmOszoGQU9HutqGQQ1t9U0hk1aSplfYS@D9Y54jC4aZN0OO3Ids@umfUb3N8cnAmm3VdCA@sYg3p6uYKjienGfDtYno59oiLNedPfhVEzbDeCGk4GFYjRcKtpzof7iz6PRxlp5Nhxz@OgRrmsuC4U2noEbaTBq9WwTxBPxE/USXONYKomV@ibDeguyC/1s7slpgQ5MweByEGq6g4mIbHOQ8yAvlRjKmoJdn5p9CGQA1YI6eY6XHngAxkE4exPgDFBTD6ZyqtD9wnLC3gk3V6hlXHrOloKwYBsGwmO9oc0Q56Az0tYJeFSYAKWFyUwVy4DJt2HjSgTS72ppHvTo/ag/IPVA4/QKjuAVY@cDw/bCmJo/wqsMFaYjM@yAaCwBdNziXrkr0EbjRROUBVojaEYc84P4juhYbiDYNPAaXJCNOCOE@NouxXnEL79ToMPk1i5OhohL2VBFUQPj8MS09CBdYmScKIMXdT/lWOh7CMW8LgjuQ3DfGHYXBHcR98hfFOxBMF6JtyDYhmC@UGV@uAvhXBFbADBE0xtU1/Ohez407J7CV1nj@uxbLrAVlskEjA2rAOMFw8sjGZ@J9epsiZcOr2yJ6gXtk6oVB8AqrYjGg@9RbaFQPGpD4fUilibnCbth9yYmLFbA4nNKCcQupq@uJPCzGAHQ/kCUstnwIHFe2mFGE/VH4/cjQXAFZP7Hj3dRJipisv7pzaD28RJC42gsh5xbER5@yVZUrjzSBxFpfhyxnj8u3QLNNcpH0CiLkQjhbStq1x0bdEuIqqKWE3njOFRlTyKfht9kpVB6RHzkzeJ@PhZnag8OU6lFZlkrcpoP56qB9R5iGtAjtyJhgZu3jPIMO/0QOpeErgF0yM2pemYm6oxopZ@a2YflJgX0UaMm3pS5oDVBNawJAueQZ/ByjcsEjmw5XeL@eCuTnURmL0DGNzmeA4JhBWjAni0Q40GfaDsaXygEcr5QXMuS3Z@D3EZsCoTVQ/j099C4kHGiyx7hRRVJkcTmsGYGPMw38qs23eSmsscl/fzMNfhKs/STNNLIZusT1bon0EuWWIGFu2nK7PZ@OfTbceYmKr6EvuMri2VFUOhBTXxIFbxdwOh7K1kyC8UmS3AcSSDJcE@XRDtD53dK0XzHeeAT2MJ4216ogSFV5WQ40swRBgGgKMdjZYXOVYtEp9gSez4MlJtspIXh/VC8VoDKXpbi4hyHc/vUecd9w/08xJF4CC4vRA3TCyizO4FuC2pwEE8zz7GYOZORn9CmL1y3rQQKk1AYCEOwbBqAsnyPUahWcfUySh6SE0ovuxBLr4N@tww@S8KL@pUyXdAd6GdIxMoFNZsyNpuYfmP7dH0ZhWNvBEkFU0JoS@LSh5Wm/RE6VIEezY0USHzcKEbbiYWcp544IR7kHcNBux0dBEZD64qM/mFBIEwNBtrRpmMqg9s5Vga@sVpsOb6JD13ssq2hThwWuhi1wzA9pKZSkTGZ6ECK36SW8iPfy7dsJ285VwzvC5dSoXmrhFdE5rbQeosXPQppQsZyMghBNYGSwtQ0x7pWwosj0fYg8Y2CZEDS8cgIMneh0a0NWj9fRj9w/TH9TmCwUNBGg6FLISIh2lDIPtofo03uBZraFSMGQU6F8EQwCk76cN8Jt1vldK4g6XjghxpD0cCYJHDlM1nG8kNChdmv0ZR8zTLMLhKBde8jH05BcVFNvpX8oOhxAxyyAmcUwdnjS38HZMfDJEg78Sf0DtnHdx0d3IcskVjvxThFInsthuAFzljJ0SyH8SvAAM74Ryenu3vHxxq3xnH7TQmnHriZGddt0C5CcRO0sLLiFALu4eSF8ggzi7h5etUIOclf4hEmK9iETeEa2cl5hZtEeQ5yOr3NZCOEVzk4sYTmoMWbj7wsiKXWA9CjkHdRNCUWLRdEC4BjrHh0LzcM08TVuS@tvgsU71i9HhDNefEoYgc6kSNB@pkwfb@BaTZD4nl4biY8lwjXeDgnKoLSzK4XAZXiQHLqJoK7ZXIElp1Jq8og0wevaMuP5noxust3wfoaDNLsCLgWFiWvlWFAJRGQi4W8nVP6PGQpESes4GF4g4eL@l0UJR9SmYB9mkwfn5IoIIsWxop1JFO1VHPs3hNufgxDSMIy3OvCo2N5U7XjjVIYRIQ4yYGYwEu9sdnWqhGWjB5IHGozcq3yVNaESeqJMk0GN3jPNKw5bSTGJUozQ4wbU08C6VDwUgwF4cSKxoKWWwsiT0TkSQwtQi0FyUrB9u1kA4esTTfxKprQP@JP0NiTxAVwqfmBjzjlY555PhGWZBAJ3SV5PpuS0mTojSzuKTJ1Ry8SpT2ZxjhfSLxycQRqdunu9iBNi0/XddyR014K5URcUASSYobvYYjgdASgB9V3URFi4K30m/yK9LnRB62wZ41ZHXVqgw5OkhJzoXjls48HduEhlcwfDQY9W2y2Y9c02yaOFCqu48RQhDGmNGjSAa7a4fBZdIm5S4iksUPEfG3zq5VFgD@6uOD35DK8iA9EK95@bQ81qe5M@BW@uDetyGckxeXbKIB7MOyLEcFLjree8FpkTQpO4OFZ7fD2Le50xlk5vJ8XurSSJP1gZJuXO5@zYqGwqRdW9RjLAlN1QVtdo5uAAxUpCCgW9EJhXV@TpB13MOHrTRRTRVxrOUSYZS@wo/8K6ibeW@1YUh16DAL08Zpty7uy2pokHVttsgG3RsQRrMp0E7UTbL5HH9Ct8BAivEvaz/ILo6GG4RP7Z36ggEmrnbMSTvEOLK9vD/lEsHtl4xXX4bR2x@313GsyROOMMucHRupbQ2DKisqSJNFhAYIW0l1oDz9wwxD3@Rot94oO9xBsAD3VxjORaH5Wwp2tdF16LDF@GWiMEkjP7Bl2H6vTHAJw60vEgYAAyFp7ZFp30iAREZ9IQ3BRcds1R3hcghGUTB6kn0ttBZq75dkgfSMGU6lQtBjtUMCnzw9O2Mnh/umb@vEeA/fR8eFXB7t7u@zZ1@z0@R7bOTz6mk5xZc8PX4B0OWH1V7vg@@r0@ODZ69ND8JDrJxBTpgCp/uprtvfDo@O9kxN2eMwOXh69OABsgP64/ur0YO8kyw5e7bx4DZ3151kGGNirw1P24uDlwSmAnR5mKdUgmhTFY4f77OXe8c5zeK0/O3hxcPo1pbh/cPoKE9uH1OrsqH58erDz@kX9mB29Pj46PNljmDFp9@Bk50X94OXergbpQ5ps76u9V6fs5Hn9xYupjB6@ebV3jMQncvlsD6isP3uxRylRPncPjvd2TjFDkWsHmAcEvsiyk6O9nQN07P1wD7JTP/46K5Ce7P3gNQBBINutv6x/DpmTlHu4AuWy8/p47yUSDZw4ef3s5PTg9PXpHvv88HCXeH2yd/zVwc7eSZlJLw5PiGGvT/ayDK/woKQBB3ALwsH97PXJAfHt4NUp9Bmvj04PDl@pUMhvgDFAZR2i7hKDD1/x3AKTDo@/RqzIByqALHvzfA/8j5GnxK06cuEEuLZzGgeDBIGJp/Fssld7n784@Hzv1c4eBh8imjcHJ3sqFNjBCQIATkz3TR0SfU25xnICurgTKqsU1NwsFSc72Gf13a8OkHIBDTXg5EDUFmLbznPBcw0Php075XbnBN7sLJ8whdx9cs/O4e4eaHz8VD458n8Nnc5WcvIuEQYdTRgIr2IWlPqq87bVGl2c207HxaF5GI3PYPf9iyyeGa8yBa9suePaADFRThFSqfPzr@rnMM49OT9Xsw@JmSDjvhhia/xdUKrIY8812jTMT9iW4oyqPRYH8GT5aRhxW8vj0Pigsny@bYlouJAEEQdmInFSFCBro2SkFSaGw2JJ0hRz0lZEx5hNG4uC6U3Xhx/nY/TC@4aYBwhnvm4hn8cxLJGBx9GxkH5IhE5qE8e10ToAu0NJar5lXV4ohXhyOOQXBio1iEOwQxgGXijqPdFb1sVU9Nx0fCIWVwCRshKc0ROcncNvUMY3wTImykXzKGcKN@3RQw2ooYRAKVR5UrS8SKw@UR7z6Ljpm9sK1XJ4vgud0fay/sODNziYKxTXylP@z0N/3rZwKSAeOAj9XYPiNenxvMkBoIHZOPwCltgTPqWaz8figFZG@mQIjAcIdRHo2m5Dn4pdddeibh2PLeJnOMTjQ2fs2eM49SCGPz@uv3z2en8fJCdSu7a1vrlRlsQxSN7wh1n@/BrToRNrkbugRV/boKZRUKyV7IDesz9zgmHsyEUsPQTEM8GDQiNPvEE63M7MdQR@6Bk3A2F2fTz2ycGTz2Q8ucmT@R3pS1JQX@e2TFEBlERWVcxN3xiThm@AqkR1wORbl3sTKrUx/iDusPkHTTzMkKhAoopZ/cFwAjUXBhck9@T9YBUojW1oiReCaHJQjwdGsAaJMwZlJi2NxSWS9CbqdqwUQa/Fgsb2SsVOMYGIpWkqgpPz6BxMSOLI9YMWzD1t8PmhqG/g/Fqc2IhBeP5WfXgCbNwPY@aCExW5zVk0DIG5WatCET1@HKZUYWhIVQVR3P6fPM8v3hqIFL6ggU0hDlYehXwOQ8gI/TStshteU/GoFcRTFjVWvEPNnZcdgaUcnFMj3oNj/RjHFZ3yR17XYRpSAPJ1ABKyM8Gm34kfhP@/IE/m4K/AgBOwR9wiOWw7I@uBnCSsnFcweiWm2NfBirHYMrWIm3GvryM0t/GC6YYZE8vwxnxiCVggSmcSeHzNz3lV5jAAKznaNeLtF09VoEbcNWDk9JTa7iM@0@85Zn@gBKekBl3FDN5mlnSubLBEDl9UPoVfYLHkXuChd09p8y3JDBxwgRRrTdhnvsxxZHSSOZjp/AoZPcJWTlUT2aAHLTyqTgXRtILGPxYrjKJeph2E3oIquvgE1nA6BA96TAj8YAYkECC09imeYcE2SLOGhM7NNy6/Jys/E7043tkDIpCfGX5Kq6d9o0NjZuyKxFJnXFONSSKez9riIM2WNbzG7qLHsdMS7wgbUz6jVeaYiLBFhmpEIHxVDbhOnex1SD2ZKbG@htS/di4dvA7D4iauAEJLHMsZ3xevsZcGndDZe1i@5SjxDLK1lkz/wKFl7yafr0TTHI3cIRUc6X/mRxwBjfMatUvohyIuGeYlespBHbWvc/YYHpRWTuQ8OGgSxgx0jPA8pf924YAA68rUGlgmnzmhEanEO7LqZ4H6gi7edkPX1@gSduYqZAqIAx9cMCvUICQZ9SZcpDnb2oi@cK9DUUrR4tMSaE7X11rLGPUNp2P07d6EVp2@d7tO3ndG/kAbTPCw9aQ1kG77ADigfWixN7bTdq999gyaAxqSTl69PjlKGv5ilq8dbvli7AtIgz2jlKUZ9B3cyOK7nSEUjVVmE3EFlBeZe8hOKCwtZNaaoAfuFvKoAkG6/VAz/vzVa/a55Vge6INHtOaSvbBNywHxAcoUrcL0u1zSIPg@pn4iUmf7qLuQZafMLJuMOqFtTxIJCGxZrFoKNEUg2BNnXaNtfgJVPWYT1GYzHOWrHRiVuu5AbNZAoykqm9zE2Rn1shIeqP3m4PQ5Dsb5wJxsM9CtBbY@tCVy1anPjbWQGc9whhNgijRtvAGy77PdaIz2agBGaTE7aVDXx0t12mj26/mQVby/S0gB6kGgqVr2FZ7gS2a4h5QRrbMVZrOIb2Wx6TUrbpgRoiNRelJUelk8yF3LsvVtdmph3WVHPcOEERY7GWH01VXQA5@5/hBBX9YZKxR1Xc/pq2iifX1S16gh4Dc41lWSDl4eHR6fAiPFuUVBxQj7TGQ@naTKV2MBO3J4nirk/h0K5AAeJGbxHTEPVfDgcAW5zGcs5JIMZW8aaO6FHPpJdZhMsmiSdz06zRU360AVSjRHSNW/RuHLp0YopRj2LJ0nG9xZT11LSCdtsaQI75C2HtSrHs6HvqPI5AcCwBqTH8TyaGTQFmcRQZn0rX5IvT0MeneDA0jTB9GGDOO2VKgc6WwatSTgnhrH07ZwjYSPRzr1/SvTA9liXEGVwyUswY4lqDMkm9QwN0bL7tnQBoAus@tih8PFVVAQZIKIH1MrUYmHByBih0S0zDlCClpX2@2HoJwqSQp36An/gT8xXZa6gGE2jrT8gWW16fiq0YCfz4ThGrTyHvQcfO9eKTq4SUoVaN2kB8IGz8kD2Tfq4YZ@3IDZ4mUuBbmBWhXs@Tzt4rCeI4IcnQypkeIxusqcEXaW4TyvSsVuQIXAuCoyYsHuS0AxyOKkFFAF5U0VglxUXbJ0JxSV9/TmTIxIJ0T6g2QA4uKzulYyIECPeRfOGQBeSashAVP7PgNi@J4l7k7YwJIvmF9cd4p72hSeR8jcRA2ZuW/juebcNuCyCxd/EVgLOMbnCC2aI5zZTYr3R@qAbxpSn4UEqPBUtxhkcQ7O3Fycq/Nx5gROMVl54FzRfjqMRdWC54If0eGCfERGRNn/3A1EL@3667l8ginM/UXPbeFhmiApIDV8TLJRwca9aQSWYHQ8lO/sTB4CWgmyJEgXe5sC3YVVoH1YNVYJLBa1M4cXlAio8rZE28cY9V3UnMiJP6JFkVNOnCiKWsfUkaJIHvcF2Y1oZYFS@MglFrVMXIkThxcpJ6P0E1H0qSiCuGSUViJKUYq2j0@VLsZA0Y/PZM4CvYRWJVEJsGpYQAWpb4z56KZAmwHJTIPneCc2LhabooIgYMNk4f5CBG9K0bkZiWl7nkbwSkvwaMW3vCzTOaSF5CFU42DpHokBgkqET@hsFkcRGVIFG@glPJNDDYgR@apQFCcmqcIM8wApkW0P92op8VTUEksNDD5riFA@dmzxpBvEA5yll@FvhSkigVycWA6EZx0IUQiMp/MwGjCU5cUSyMGCFPXM9BYTcFCCEpfftGSMdwOKkmhXgeQOcXLnjOwGVOjP0VFKEt@U7YNex32xR4mJhhNU@PBseaHkWWMYntEcM6Gg/ie0WAtPftBEKD0E8Y0o5WbQayRzsRB6uiuZBxPrVUIu3AUcMDvk00Lgxb0NsQ5tCCjvOHiMdS/QSCxYF3TBaZ@zjLQUe0h70V3T5hIqybaY0OVxs3MEcLLIA@KyU7mSYufLiBxOdyNSoudMVBIl9oZ357DP@OnCHJEqJWIh/xcVOC53jDfshXA6hxPFvqhGhLiCcr@rWoTAQbnfVS04cKzY764WwQHTIWsp/nS9SJQEZwEuShQjBrIpxWVQEDCOQ42noIigSTN@wIzVU@ZQG5OqwtYpzahKIYvEeXLJNOgx5gUjrh9LVkdgXiMsjWaUW@jjzEurHR6TIXIfDpFqcrJL4KU5fToUZjpIgcqoqeI9JmEEkNjcCCbGzH2@dpOOGUrzAQuNQfEo1YtucndvAm3QqxTUWYUyOFIpIr4yl/jc7NFW0RCrNHtpT7i6TFCNC55cr43QsjRnxle6h6pMjKpk7mIllGTxAky5B2HKPQBTPoZJNOxV6C/JmfLw8GDrPhRnZ7M46PEWBlICB0jato1GbBwHXxuT@3AugbKVojV1Bl9VFkaI9OT7cDyZxkGHtXfD2Tjh2TXQ6vbB8tzpo9IWcjZZV@ZQFFKVmiUri2SR1KbxroALVCUa22qXra4djgRS95c0P1NCRMalxN1wEiiVPOooRBa1f30B/7KxYk22B054wgwD2rL0ic1BQ0ZwCxPfKhZGiAmy5DhUBCQZcXfotPCj0er0SRN4Cv3CaOq9OXnKDT4xo5MOWeMSK1HjgiFcJJyC3iqQb/OGZ/emn5qb/sAdgI7TmUsAwffRjs@NUlMiPVJNp4bWD@rL5vZns/mK621TB8Y9vJE/nsl6EbKOG9OhUTvWtej978Is8hKUwG@hyTeCOrKAyM/mEokT7YYwbjFn1G9ZnvSQps5jaPjgY6TFNVeSUilWN2HILA4uomuj6ExlSySJajBWBJ@NBjhf4/PFndi40UZm8Qo8DYv3tBO0JmMSZKPtW4YjTjISHeaFh/MXIWwWz1THzV2Ugu2YwGjfipk/3/GLQtqWCMEVyXewtTy/7LFW0z3ynIpslJIgi@uayiQ5puW@CxScUKshqNK0ohLUHZwMXeGaudCXQDFX55vAHqI93aUQQSVelKQY8E6hvruOlhYzczQIWRkWzQNYOU/dCq3cD1C3Jg9Vt/4LcHK6QKWYW2gPooMt3SvUpgf5dEtucFp2f87RLV@d7u8nDjxpTYJRQd/y1guFAh6CM3MlHk5Q4Cyx7eaT0Hm0iecH1194X7XyGDV5Cd7cO/CQBgBFaJyawHqCUxMj6G9ip3KhPcfBXTnvfQ7JT@BpM1rGaYeL2786pcpHKJF5Vom9wwxi/t6x4M5pUBz5kEFgCdabQWxUQ6/kYJkcsAc9OniiTrgkjZDRuFnsWsCJj2rtRnok7oUkOx/e4aPeRNsQ5edWr@dm2RvX67WXZL47NBlhfz8eocBBcCkhbzw@3SmRZdaV3Yvdq4EgsfvO@cVMeOkut37SXibPGuBMmoL92LF1sTceKHLjrQwVE7KcwWxmmNzE7T0XMnRRMk2h34@WH2MGZD8Ium8MFJP4NA0MfaDYSxW5gKJVvHmTrw5Ge8oOZBkXcygJEJWfC8N5dj80MnU@udp713YUyDoGS7hdjrZ@U/FSThaAh8yVz8Z6B3lY4DgETXhu4sNi3Jbx0Knf/oPWbbQc4OZGsvGGW2Jj543F8xEY47FlsathpwPNi1via8FRYwE6EpU5nVYpIGtEwXrWNyPQZ5R0xxfH3uFSm5OJYyYIaRSbWSYOxyv/bnmUghYomh/wE5dNfJmDZr0/ostVInlGZjhcQDErdzDCOUaQpM/M6jfXSr1eZ8uDTIbV68/Akcux@rM620WPZ8/YLrw/w/fH1eL6epmvnNtVb8DzWeB5y54BDuqC8CK3XXiFMLqfCYdSWMTL@epytrx8Xq3Uyn6@UX/WzOcvwPW3v/eTv/3Hf5yvi5fv8OUZvTTehkCapuWXzZvlx7dlfG/sNtPLrcbyoJm@KGMtQ3H/2vONnhHbJqaZfy@X6QY7502VgUarVqtplv74kbvOhpHTi5x480EU3egNugZFZ4ShVk3X048fg6tSTf8oreLJHcLfCP0/gD9TUZbTfDGxlqaP6yc7Bwfxy4XCS0s7qGnihLshFqfZjm9Dpt6lgtnzXINpGmvm2LuQPFzQfc4B/9/2rra3beQIf7Z@xZpEopdIkeTkHOfFOuSuLZAC7QHXAv0gBZZMUz4BssQT6cRCqv72zjwz@0KKie0gveYO@ZCYkrhvs7Mzz8zOzpa7aJocMSqd@Y920o4O0feIUkXDEn6KACOJe5JotKv8EuFFNkAJvyEYjAs9uHghoXOo4xEJPH7/pRxKbcly4@FTdznW7bQ3Hh5/97YXxzFaRnTuWQIxh9Yyf79xEgTLItJNMupltGRo7Fwbd3lsqEImRhw/SKgfDxPN47DChZI8YOQrbMbNIDWGoS6lchXhgbu/1wBt6Mky1rDoHSnzaxy3ZmywvWvgHnXAXZtuPhhc6RvJTbXb4AbB4PZgznhSvVreJej0l8vjbnlbYVLJxFCtUIhH1j046FTHaD8T3Nhnqqle8WOe2p0lPXG/Xm4vl3zjJg5N5O9JOhHl2zpZy5XNisgtSMnzdM4bn7KiZcL8oT0Aw5TPwq4S3l3gJKRLzrwrgM/etUwIktYDIxzNwzHnM9@t5UqOCqzn9EgKnxMiyp3SYMNHSO4kDMWbakgRI@WtHOhkhF0zeZOpSp99mC3Yg4O8NUDjYD/gMmtrSWzoKadlY47oG761NwC0dSVFWCsuZIdQ5RWboOwUIaLwm4@RsJZEw9ZMl6tp3V3TiFJEk9LMkUQik8RyzSx04xXNyaHfqC2j4fS2q1mh5M3Web7QQBWdJkThyCnhDdU6aTakMeWW8DbuTuZWVDg@y0rpDfE5@8Ek5wi1ToNULii9yMGbHHkocXFxKR4XV7KzyD1Pi0UiR6Wk9UMrizOkA@FvJW/KRxsi40HCQe0Eo4WJ0VOoGgmKqfb1gE58KpnX/y8Oes9AMxtiJP21WVuysWMONzsTTyRfo@MEVFAmivYRziml4EGJMZfp5aIolenKoWs9Xyqj2FnS8yKfIuIxoG6FshwbZK/DdiJhqvS2QdgseO1vJGhPJLq6nvfsYFirSSyWKylDQuKMk33@cPLIdifsNa1gIh8v3255hqBcWdctcuFjmRPPqsbPwidbQOXaRZEXHZzkRwUqLao06Y35UuAKNUicVpaBl8KDUvUBAzNzh5ocMqpCXpkugQR7wtvyi@3pruaS@/9lu6WpPN9wqllafPQW8wHpaB9Mfk5vrBKPblyVtSvwfWqBOovfBc4vba6XhPwlSF01SniPvG/U9aPSlB26znAPSCmzCcvGzXAuK0XteH3pt@XSvabkbvhgMzi0AqSTtTWxg/56IMqctKmtV1IztAb2487mkNAUDC4y3c6OkhzqdTZn8nCsO0tzPzm7OtawNryV8nbMiiw4NCasHHUh95C@F8b71xBpBxfO6@ti/ab48pgevjv0ZjF3X@KuesIFM4LBChFm7b4@0eMY915/IbOA5cCCBIGcVJnlKT03GoI81MKM/pZf/rC@aQ26k2gSdYfHz9sR7GSHw@IkJ8soTlKOqN6wlZCq7UmaWCPk3qUiwjfni4sLQhx64wIV1dbcT2da7Zg95B@cuMt7ULURhHgaBbI879Ek4gulNZ6zzezyaobHv6//uZlt35ASwsefVjKf/@D6fiZlxDev4pefZY2@viCoEe3YTvY8cachwmU@I@STFIAGRSqpEhxcqCFAukcAadONPy8PNiBDOH7xXTj0DL1JkzoVhJJLbPhUcgJOYQLw8QSy087kO@JNNWFy5LOTR/wkBkEVQPIP9iRP8K2UEKi/NCMuU0rp5zOqgfFaaE1Kdc2SGHRgTa5PD2UtJx@nrvf5VA2bIvnl7Op6WSx0ZHvDsuPiQl0jpLjma0l0mJxFkLPhLU75ANQr/Ij0yhajs8uwSrtgHFzveEGr1NsyEFSeCmqE2VoC@9GSG@OH29GDBjVVJIP70VPwx2D38hNzI@h@ZE0NTrDOSdyC6cB4meaBuSEZB52eNW7UhyXjg/tBROFudDKWySKad@Ec8wxzCngIEze5v4XN/ns2cuUbJtmZp5K1SzWMWmSYt/VxfrhrBj3sFoRWLXEKCufrKxttqeZEYLwGd0PTCuIT5P9vg/UWy62E/gJS2fOZIXY5LC20Eji0B@MCcjoQA80czgLGGoKREElA5GSaAU3oHAVJK1nX14gNMUroTelzFWRbxORGWiPeqIo95dl1MGLvp7ZFbw4B4VXiqQsrVFW7ecWmm8Hs1fMazPa1jClDyG68AvWYtcYId2xwK6HSfUINP49Q0q86OskvX4xMZQKUqbRrNOrY14kOPTAarnWXK2BPLoFwhw4IV@qoAbrY1ww6Vq2OJtAi@@cWDHfM60sSi2UsLFEDM/@dWD1iQOaV3FDOESdHaq436QtCxISuGvSPIC9LKZyPK3lACLL2G@4lZIJgaoDezhuhuclMP243dGe2L6FEreGzYRuN3KGlRunejHvDexGDvBUz30tzwQoFkKNjzjRVyO3aD7ruI27p0vhqXdIkkb1TWsRzJ8v4yO5tXup@bG/YMlS9aZvPdFDDV3IkOoj9PP24cUBdEKTBAVvUGEo/UgdvntIwMntkRty5PvGH2IfW0f01@b8tjXOk5Hcc4ADCwKIDxmdcq06wIgSEEmKBNh/kTSK1OzBf24qHaoCLIG2Jk60GH6qqrnUIuVmBls6tTxFQO/Aq1npNrYfIxLXFTEvO986W2DpKE3aEOy9V3g78wep26DdttmjulqREcVWWxFU4nIcPjfYNLusKxqg19EuEkn6UiDFZiXCusi4JIf4ShFeVQsvEob6s1v8gL@gbfnU@rAciLF49DvEemr6n@/XKUb6eOij6KfrwgC7XlVQCoIncX2eTPPreNO5L0Co9b2FSOPR@P1x6r5m4K6u6ROn1vCi6@NlQdHGoe7Z5n70NrH0kH79k9EEKGa9/TCdMs3Qg@hduCvpPGJTv7ZoVLl0YSfu8kMjRtg/yyIvHeQH19dJvP7IdJzppdnFB6viaT@NvC6qCD@LjprqAzlIoh0lxP4VpjXRpXkUhmZjclaplpqW9XWZgmAXmr80/BkrNNWHTAVWH8CLkbOGtq3UiGcA4CJCdA4grhV07FLOIDSIpOOaPmkjlYC75yOe6kmUEpnOmzeoYtD8YhGCsHzaz4k4Qy2/Jyel2s@JssHzXQIUP88cNvnPzvpDsLrisc2dcFnfg0@54eNaJM8IWTz6zjt8Wp3kHLdUTuZ5HvFDhwIfJQSSmCVpuu6EzX6VWuOX2@bDvG3z5WhVD56uHLx1H/qQMYjoexCS1IMa/oKUSdryhnHsf4oGW7QoWckdhj7S3LrdH68a2t65tL085w7Dx72nhNZrlr2uaLd6vtYRjVG0Q/sfahljWypqeRrq2p6a1v6Blvr0afvJNDf@x1XDf0YKvFbhF0wRT/23u/whzz4nqlyeDk8HZF9v3dd9FIWNFlf1WY6JDMxx9/2xy86fB5Ob5059@jYt4dNT/14b@FvGv8fFJLI/0QJ@e2E/v4lH8il873sXb/unpKT1qLa//QrWM/urq5Le2r@i/0Xe23uNtPOqdovi/49ExPQyPjqgnk5s/P5/cnAz4X/Tya4If4e6KAx8fqzVD9kpVCLm9sssZ7uvcV/ljoB3eMAtYc7zsIGXNT5X20GEOnrk5OhkoViEGkix77zgD4WJeuDNVih@R56tAtkI5cWGz7GmsnhSiFeCaaNMfNAFtr9DLZ/azSf0YJfhOm@mDx8e8dT3VZH@uAy69H2CmhHKTedFCw5zImP@OBt9HLv3fi0izA0ZhxL/ubapWPFGt@F8)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
159 [Agda (too slow for driver)](https://tio.run/##VczNCoJAHATw@z7FINEhWP/QA0hi9gGFUN0iYt3VlFZX3O1S9Oyb3uwyML@ByYWtvJcK5JqONU9V9@AdjrE27dtQYlTBdAteWveHINM5Eg8laMq0YFI4RJBDCfW4MzYmuASvQS/bk61EX1A8KLdO6TpHMPtc9tk92Rzi7fm6un2DyQGi@ZKFNIL3SbZOsUtP6Q8),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
177 [1l_a](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/1l/impl/1l_a_mmi.c),
181 [Ropy](https://github.com/tormaroe/ropy/blob/master/ruby/ropy.rb)</sup>

I only tested about half of the image based languages since the resulting image from the program is not changed from the previous polyglot.

I was unable to get the interpreters working for cockfuck and 2L. I don't believe that any of my changes would have broken the cockfuck or 2L parts of the code but confirmation either way would be appreciated.

### Explanation

The SWI Prolog interpreter is *very* lenient in terms of dealing with errors.  For the most part any parsing error will fall under `Syntax error: Operator expected`. Most of the significant changes are on a single line that I added:

```
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
```

`:-write(186).` does all the heavy lifting, outputting `186` when the file is run. The rest of the line is devoted to handling errors that prevented the Prolog interpreter for running the code. The `` ` `` near the start of the line is required to close an open `` ` `` earlier in the code. The later `` ` `` is required for pip to still work. The line needs to start with a `#` since it is in the section of the code that is not in an asm block comment. The `end_of_fine.` tells the Prolog interpreter to stop looking later in the file reducing the chance of encountering further errors.

Outside of that line, I added a new line containing only two spaces a few lines above to make Retina happy. To allow me to use a `w` for `write` I removed a `w` from the Haskell right above.

Finally, to make Incident work, I replace an `xx` early in the code with `86`, slipped in an `R` after an existing `+`, put two spaces after a `}` in the Haskell code right above mine, included an additional `fi` and `le.` in the line of code that I added, and inserted a space before a `w` in a line containing mostly Grass code.

Answer (score 8):

## 190. Ruby 2.5.0, 9370 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNJkiD2XHn6B3oJJtiFTAKZ@CBBggCBKvCri91VxRqS1TU9IAqVABJANhOZaGSCBIrFtjlJNrq9vYe7vdXa3q3uZmYlmfbhzLQm04PObs1kpns9W7vf0PskW5PZ/IORu0fkB75I1szurUACGRkfHh4eHh4eXx4tw@v/9rcJ/LA3rj3t2a7PfNPzWWdkXZsjne1P2XPD8gr5TUnCWLVRbzwwHd8rSQmWY8wxb9iJ07Y64Md898p0rI/mCMLyjA1Hbm9kDJjfN3x4sSAVOzTtT4NPPmu7g4HhdDyIucnYGwMCu@P2FTNanj8y2r7lOhC0xdhbxzYGrY7BIIY5Go5Mn8AXGIBoX1Ga2ZBtxl65I8/E7Num57noucPYnjkY@tMqvBQhhjGy3Je111/OJd5l7EsDMBva5mQOl1yWvbPMUWcuRS7Hvrk4Pp73zbOvNddhx4v45TbZ25Fn2MY8/C1WG/vuiT/vX2C1nukYLK/v6vn5wG22PzIWkuywkWl0upZt6pbTZhrrm/bQHDH0YV13BFXmm3YxW8w2a1FKvY1pi1HgPNhdZm9u@nPlyWeB3u6obzqAYXY@MBcGzgXkw4CORRkYoylTvL478hkgOPbMDrtxRx2PuY49VdOQnk0@spbhmdtbCGAzBHDluDcO8IrvQtW2pr7JHNfRKDFG3GK5l815/skX0Ld2ejLvv83yL@f9dmLMky@yM3c4nY@yy15ZL5cx6maWHQ3c76wDtwMVEA/jDerNyO2M25bTg2ZiQvhw7FM1eVIb6rXKhqJZ6uhgCapYHg2An7sDMw7Tg/YIdPOGZtvqWm1e3@bENx0PKOzpzAJ2vLFsm3VMGxJE0Ntp5rlI9cirZRt9va1LyC@YCxtc2cxi7eGQ8SBmW4DScbbITCwh@wjhdt9jk@GAedYAgv222@2aJvtoDvuQXOq4EoNPezhXrPBt3YQ4jhmQxhxCO0XSuNiagU4BhW5GxhAY2hM08K2B6THLT3rMNDwLBRgk8UynQ1QdhqLNZcYMJ7JrC9ohFH08ItieOaKWQHCh1YxMAGmEkky5GVm@T8zMauyNaYzYxcg0VS7iTK9tDAGPmSwhMxdz8LEgOlXq3l7y6PQ4CZXLU@jGECpztHnxk68kg@kVtt4sw7ciy2Xp6PUhu12/RDcXocAAw5FiqKzyA/Myl5cmfCe5VqY3upMAqgRUsVnGHfoZQxsCgpoPCGYMdKJLu87rQzuWMdubq4sYy/FYHagNkAnsmzSVrD0ejVDYR0Q1rqDQtuv0gJ5Q2NHYQXo4bDsLVdB2QcqnmXkNVAOBSHUEzRUpfNG3oNI8rJKYoOH9DxEUeiBgY0HRIF/PtccUD1J6PvIyUAWSIsSTLvuGdQ3LxiQQjqA41iPTG9s@phk7Haz5geWYHZ0FaLSheUKkgXsN2RkAlDyA9QexdklIQWSoCJeKikE//vM/6/R6AKfWboPIEez6Deu4beopDUIW@jqGDAtyzia0IF4ac@fJIYNrw7Y6ho/ZO1ORBSFBud64Y7vDXMhwdGNBK@0b19CyoXG1fZMzuTv2Acc0GxhXXJpYnHOh4AOjBRVLGVDeVGyNPT@AWmqbUoJ4RhuM/W6RacMjlvQy75VnJeXZ2qUJyKm6urGeyfTKwHD6BnnBW/I@zvmmNtNzeL7huVZHGk79vuvkmdZmcrviDk1HSc7ASKaTo1ZS1VHKKWrZqrT1ruV0lOQe8GIVMk6q5XalXbdKjfJc8niWAOYGwWBzNZW2KksgcqhRXGcGoGvoIMC/0YQrFuZ6TSQ5BusxbyTMvN8190iQJoN86SKDgBzSPds0h0pWz6koJjDe0nJjwLKSzsEQBS5ZjVQykUzFi04QoKQzBcXGemG5KLbsYR/VDyCK4w2hJxgh77ahA0XJ6Fk@aHhp1iK@pl4EJAvJxBszOTKxpw35iJokb3KYXkNBKSBETWi2JZudWEMGIQBt2fcWpLHt3kCGhBN2MyA6HMzU6EHVQGJekBovCM@JfGaLxPt/gNYyWVFrWdAIsLmBTBc8HysbRN/M8zgAjTeSmOwZGFOA0ubdatRgmNWFtjQA8QBKSttEmQPCx@QdCmYypvbngRrM3C7LavlCYbaNLTQxf5SpaT8DIf0xc29LwsLHGxMKGtYFrds2nN7Y6JlcQWJGu20OfSGooCSeD6Jovr8hT010nrrXl9afz@dNnUigWkR5oJDntSe6QgOli9DiNRuEKTPE0AAUuhGIJXs6nztEuJ7LXP6AUWYQ@CCvQCHQAIDJzInZHvsg1YCBb/pWuw88i9g5XC7yTmg@e/CK5w6SXeuGWSMyuerTvKRnQi9EYyUIDWt0EQ50rgiqOuNBlR/3uB@y4Q2WAHZDFKEjiPnqGUMH3nsA5sB13CVAgZAhWIwyG8LrATSxc1QooeMK1C5qrKGWGVYR1Bnq5x3kv77vD70S9BOW3x@3dOCUzMVoeuKfOsgsGX80tXyXu1u22wKx7EH7zAQ5ZNrjljWZKxD5hXX4nSddgwLW9VgFeu7vx8B1SrLrgcAk/wOMHAuSSXATCP4rQ0SKpAOhlK5HovgYhMr51Gkrsk5NSYdGJ6eZjA1XhlGIjKlCuhy4A5RC7B0pBqjpwWjMcnBUKmQ@iXxjaVcXyn7S65JJ/TvXcpTb5NraWrKUrIJkX1t7Bq49dD1DVwpcz8ilkQvj6eiiFGlyYWidUqBfI3lXDyBP1AZW2wR7pY/WUDHqpdJmI23Uc@KZx6cKog4kG8TW8AFwkmqlgk5Vlas3UFC91Z0t/QFK5/P2yBoKInxlXBv8XVBhk8hgDYY4uhuZZexk76fJoDKCXhCU1nZfGSUv69nLxuXtZSd1eZdMY2q1bFRaUCjITxnovZE7hu5SrW@VtFxDVeub0Em2KslsckNRipoNGRmq@kVRTRmc2krSBKmtXF4mgaiCPvV2f0TwJum8qoakAjywYwadUEnqt0XIv6U21FQS0qrJNAwxKskkUKaNRPCo0MiZMwQ6PfuaE@YglZKIDd3RFX4XxD746TDA4smPgX8PzmdHo4MrkK6s7dmoimgjro3Aa2aDe3boEWpcJXZCGqsD3S2UAHrbTjgywkGyMyb9mZRbN54RDQcxBvlh34Ny1ZqJg4C71gQGCNDup4EihP036kIHMOB0bVN/R6qJzKDhMGzu@lJt6A3vVvS2F/EA6D3gHNpGGxr2LLhLmV0CQODzTGZ5iFpeADyvKtGo5qEyQsfSNhykX8cirX1seX0kL2hWOJQYdYGqqLKDbmAS1U5YG/r8HlDanFg@1@GBj84xyQvDU1TUGmtc60JlDzUGRCqYA6Du3G3DeMcEzQFD@eCRHTnX1sh1kMj6EYAGhi9jHcwBX0ZeYKNa7SR/uJq@y4ADxRa8czHaxqHOE7fttVnGcW2357INiICsqeucsU@cNqAAOp8Pw0vmWR@JQLWe60zneNDE7t5DHTG3vRlq3wbGzFB8/TuQNWx5oaMIK8p8fvKzI@ghcoVsFvAP3rL0CQsZgzJfRvRssyiCmCK1kW@wJn9mDvvTmUkf5A8@igR@ck3eMPm43oAOFbASLfwjJY03cu4D7TwI6gSuZWU/Ig0JpzLio4yZ0oMyCO1UFIc3GyhhYs4bfQNSzABdqPCofo9Bdl70x6Zktvsuky9Bw8hXWaZjXmdQ4Mgg6PqgKmuQlTkiZSxMJuaHJd8dg1bXMW1rYPknNN1lO6i6RN1yEIozaxGAN5bpS2K8EYlXnJKKZK3T4/GPJtgheZJJT/b69PCo@aZ28aIiZ8beKGNbLeDgjtkcgOJpm57M5j8JdmYCMJH@45V95rp@hVfXlc0e/CQwTZD85WHz5cn@We3sW44EgfGswdg2EJXS@lwETH5OwUGris0DdkfuINTIPVER65tI@mEw2Y79lAjYwoCxmGrHEavwL6B/MNGOmqvw30b/AU6z622p124zzeWvoaeIWKSIONuuj1qB5y56hvPsMzPQ0Pf1UikEtyx8dSIB@TaXvUPgNzhTHyvfbS5H/td@tzvjnSfvKw152o68N8mbz9PPzpCLwi4ELY0cwtsieHx@fym8haClkUN4BQ4P1wWWg5sLWRY1BLZNwHAdYSmsuYAlEUNIOwQpvvYQhRUpbNXCg8hrafDKRCHsXYKNixMRKFqqEF5BxDznjgFfOPCaOBk6jUJzM6EYxJcbmNaBUcgeRkF@@YQLEeAF6po37Oj@xI9AbMZBaKBc8GWIMJwzQs5uGs3BwIqwDXxiQUyzQVLltqPEhTCxO5fUtSLvMDqv17zdBAVoHGuogU88KEzEq2nkDqexBnub5xQeWEJCxJrQJqcpLQGgrkMDM7G4cQGd4EsXVJeXFk4gdWdklBSq2JeSHIwTZhRiOQrJR/N1TLtePtEoxwGR9BxYzpWLw9PI1czquQJCCUEMruzFlF3Q8uhnJuoCUoshXGoPWl36WRKhJOawoIPCRRmkylc4D4/TbK6LC6oUjUbjBAyoZTlG5oweOC5fhs/sDMMMMi2zOwZ1NAPDJXQ/EE3bLVLMbqtlrYoKdEHUg@eSaKNxaxnZoDn1Fyah2Azh/fHIt82OeP6nn3egAharp29MSQUPHU2gG/FGd2VtiaT4Qj/La5bifDe2LYPIQK6HQLYNnPc37NCxHDTqEkzT@sZogJquqFxgTvyBVnMPn3HMR6Y97pjBc3kmROLZqS6e2rEGVCJ44lCNBqYrks9N1PH0NNixXaNDUPiQxDKj2ub1Yk64ch7TeUGOPALPYD6NRQtYfn/sj/kvrlk9VK/WEL/LqVKaZbJswWjlzIzrGS3LvIcPRsbVuONqw6seFRpR217F7bwR4fSP1rWNK@5sonM5AXgRR1avZ46C56poN33Qsml4kLmhx0Os4jljb6i1oLp8aEv0Rq1jcE8OI5v/ropiiW0eoWM11Sybfj6HPYlh2tCGkNC4TK3FiGbNkdk2WlMcNPU/n88wQ9IwQQxV2qlUdhO7xHBNIloQHw5Xp8d@lNLv7i5PzRfIOUmWDSUyfGFc4xNGVGaxVP5AxUI/Zg0MW8t3Ys6VIj2YjIxcS6LSCFpr24YHrOWL6jCvofro5z52x66pDQOQUeS6h9kjdIKlqVWrHFGaIegUtuUNefsTL6tk6/z8cAQGdyrQT5QU3xbp2yHd1etroWu5eHDbPq40rOC3R4g7PsmPyygxBtLdVbRruzf4Xalw9N1rk/8u7wI/LsXqEYJLs4kzrPaS5J32Q@yKa9X0s5yKV0ux8tv2Un8xoz6rvT@WoT3Ldj0YL@PvfYQAhdjz@O9yVo7TzDIcjSZ@4@7lyQRSQ6aLia4VNWnYPdfeLvYyBvysrO7xqIudgXg@VuyFYiuXe1hsBbqS6@TEc6W8v8qMrh7iBJodHuEqUsx5T9e7THaJ1YfVBYQRBS4NLy/ccbZIKfUMn6lYVQGjdv/GmAbP36FLWUXdoEsZTknTBlUQE@wWweGPuPb9u@S2dX9unccJpAWwOw8VIla5V7YJ4pl@F6qU5bO5z0yRy2YfL5669tgcm0t1vtPWdybuv@TTrLijwLBtvjx5cXL6mUhlRTHWxTRfBoiHk3xhrI9iHPkorLHzxrd7BYxhW9DIH1Rxlsq7IajnQxx6vwHHG3QsJuw54@FM5cZodzZ2zu6nXH8YtGy3M4MkhnyuRCo@rEjNaPCeSd9V2v7RwIXRsjsAhcF5RP0LoDSHwX9nAJNPpGbMTHUszT5cagaFFhQPqFHrytNwzvpxQie/aohPkXd3YRDnmP4Uf1dRepkQbbmu/Tk1A7K0Y9HeXFvDbZ8P1dCCkiN2HbBoMsPDiZFWd9U0Bu9nxHgTqIdja/@e0XR8LvuhASJVm4aLgdD4enOv90/zxGbGH8oFem@aO/JG7cC9iknPsKHn9KK@cy@Lcr3UbZm2wR@T7a374O3qm/fCCzURofDSIgouvPCllmitKjEnjoZTIJbVgUFL3xyY9HqPtm90vht7wWNlpImL36XF0TOTI7O9KuXQAgng4O/Mwk5MR/JdBwZavjHqmThSsXHFUfiukrrBQsVSfE4GRs/kG/rvEyjR9AVuUuPju8i5fCKjxPeNtCEZX1a/nxmgOV2ZUy94LgX4atqGGh0P7oW2rOW3cZb0waauZ5auzzygBDp9t@/0zf6Imkf4tqqBAE/6/CjGfYUA/PuGd4W78khKRSO8vhenru3a9mOoi1KSy0zXXT6Be4Q76juQ9LPgTo0WBIjHg3N90JETkahHX9V6@uYY@ivP9d2hqdHbqqg2TgHx31WyNFgz@13nlu4d9wNFgufvCv/BwWbPcP3hkB7NoT326IeSat3ls50ldkzZPIYrLJ9v6@C8a/bcVrtvPYRSyzR8x7rKBPM8/PXeYeswRgWLaYfordsWEG801ZEbKvHwc3ycrKrS2HrN0tIfjEej6cMSYnaxPpyc5UsK6FiVv1huXRJMGgHuWwr259yzriFWZ1eyF@nXqEtrZhaUltzK6aGZLVpCjNEy4QqdaK7chExsMfxzpjfFOj5N9FmxWVjwXza3sUoivhCCDgaNyotxz1MfZtx@B1Qu/FkKsNbDE0t86cmz3ZvY1DT0R4YjHkvS6plwHfG@VZTCvcsoy8isZ8SKpmaOV06H2dbQ479M6@aXore4RL8Ya7p8cCyqrGN2@e9DSt/AHeG@ddAttPbI9No4S45imatSXAQ5bg/Es2azKHIQdyn6izsClikts12f9tPXZs/AfWwvLdzSZnuLvSFAnt8c8BjAPxkbnvWTseubS2HObxJ4DMhXRs9qv5ipgQBgQF2x6Yk/ZhoFei1WxE3f8mj7cOBY3pA4i9F6@2Lg/ER8eIzt/nmTmMIkdnEy7YQFuz1DBy4FYLixNK9ZdVSswq8UfJZP86viubScyzdU3DfpcDMeDMeeeCzPfYCHAeLTzIMr8vduLJCK2vcghFnfsP3lU9GxuVZQtETPGDlXqd8/s2y3x35WzDLQy0DgoTa@grH2oZ9@Y/jQAhxvmTpIA6W8XsDjqqvFJ9/CcEan2cJzD15abNcDP2skDl15enCyMUFbG@kURLArniXwbMYYxb/vjnRG8RTFSKVUVeKJcH6950C0IBadLcNzJ/zYmsdsy/MprtVl9Tpbv52UsqXcHaswuSSzRoNDxQ@dgjiaDOlg2BlPXl83GpX1pKYl15OXTollk2F00wbGWRrdmInbtejB8Y1IwByDb2BFd1DiMj9X4/XpzBooTR1Qvt46NGUC/eeInw7hR48ucJn/P/5FRxzlg6GaB1oLCG4gCJ5kdQdm3715xvMVudeGQwOPAiIMaOc2P5iiHdQYMCBoafwEn3vD3h5fFMW5IHFsFl7e8F48xIJXLk4j4K5en1cexybcoSkyDlMFhWq79njggObc8fuezs4t2rA7HkU778CF0Rx/hKOETpqdsI6Jy6e0D5uGxrbrXtGBCsTkP/4FPw1Fu7HFLtkgezoFGcsRN13n6AhSu@2OAesAyEdz5IooChIZWv0YJ6KAuU3ur@IeZTqmBRypBYeUKBt@Uumgds60I5bEE8F49qFsdZX12tmX39SzjcoPbJAx/9PPM@qtIJz8hba77clpFkQp3yFjxYMLEByFJpm8PpF5huFWdUtsVb/h9QEkMjiT4W71gMdcdyhaDR00pXOVITfy5sgUdFM9B6eVBnRGlRjWvKHTSrRF1EFpiIc/HQ8aGLyqBJq3usq6MuZzI9q5zwqQIZ74MsDFT7XS5m08eYNJ1ifsE@sjk8E4JVfIwhsnpI2HvQaV/WB3zWZ8D1Tm0GyNaeH/Oq/nNytUnPVmZa9KrpHZcfHQZf395SSf1S4nO0eNjBcQ9fJy8kU2/1OgujuCVE8z2PKOXh/eruvV7KdPnjFlsnyXLPONWiAm1m/fnLw5Or@oXbw9h1q4C8TPsTsaGJGsQS6iLcJ916bjrECXkWV6nyF/wjeIrihs3WB7aD9BVaX47leKKmgta/I6d8ZE00zqB5IvS@@ZsfDFCEKmdS0WcNQJdANYh8BsSDUs/HiIh3KZSCsOFhKXWSjjsQGFhMHtcEtkKZFKZhUglgbEeiSp2OrCPuN@j6HYg1DuJ9uzpVGQYmF@9TCcF3EpCe7@Tso9hI7y9y83h3J/uSnOPeWGqKFvkOa4dvLy7dnRbDLgMXqS1K3sFsS2by6csaXxhZPgJCWdkBEJcVapIjOZEvBX0ZmRcYyW6d@YUCwhHNsDnpg4lPCXpYgxgTIVtDDSKHNaKAphgDpIGYs1tyu9a01iKAZ9dAzcLS9iKASO5RB0gLguC8gJMiuh4ycoBkIV5Aqa3hsS4kJeJ724@pMOWhwWDfto0Esp1YquKux1PAb/sV4pcOUbbMJEd5ZrMI3l4WubMCbrh3HVMu@j2DonhLzOcZdDfNGkAeDU@c6gMRztyxIb76GXto0hnp8WsV/DuKnEvh@7dMonECahfnGDIwSDW@@gqm0bWBo6PeT4eBY66LcI3snxeQW1M66akXyP89zYwY4KIsVsaRxNQPkHZuuSrOen8jnJXXEAPOgqQYXq87Odhh1pCR67tjyrZXP@6qKOY4OkxNKIgqN9GTrfxWq2BzpJB7pvbo2FlBOdNgzzXcOaw@QE8KQeqoxpJksY16ssHgiGrvSmDd3qB554neIRZC8GM7m3pmlAuZ7lMM@xYGjml9h30NBxdqHE/NEYF9yryYUkAQolcml9f2DHIi4xjXBpZn7853/GzSFc@uD@A@GeZPfh7Q/FWxfc/ywIyeXg7V@Eb3l4@yP@9j6DVbZ4BnwBT2znomAcv7AGsfa@OXnDPNBPef0MjEmM9Cg1kI8sB2hgDaCir6neMDrPIaqWCI5S/waqHXgF6hxVFtRSKD9z1FDwdG8pk0GNHkduOu3BNSd8hpQO@34/RiMXoFhltgvbW7kMIKldBwDpxF0PN31ygKpaAjknXVvDyodWG/faM9lrG7ZZ2S7z@s6sG@835Q8housQV@LKf51BGtyeH6aAsKpIpqwbqZyKSbFzSuaSKKc6Lmcf0PAUckAUFb2d4MgSqJCuIBXwpmNOfNKCpsGgpoU2hnAmx@SmTgJAGgDisNEUw3wTi7Zx4q73WKPT49Ugv8No5xitJC9jwPp7dulfOg1hkoMBM/1qCTs64P6nS@x0cM7CM4iLBiKUefMOWBr2/NxxcbvvMWDLlHwmv5nJbasxDpUFKMAXm@8nAAkNFgRA27S@c4de7eDo5KvTN@cLhg4oZnI@WpIlq3upS01P1xuhIxniPUvU/ePM@av944CUcayi5W@MEa2Bz6O5LLd5TFfk/o7vmF3MmwIWMsplHwuYlpa0Y9oisgg9Cs3EIh7wnXoLuSrq7V29sVe9dBIL2X9aZvwloW8gc4Hr0iPTL8l5NBHF0O7bBdp98/TgSEgOz4PgJmHfvYpOnQiPWACPHkABCSDpmSDWClmICJzyOZfA/JfHzc55JPj4rAwZ5AjxCeNdBObpsFlFp/PFsfS@4fVtqyXdiBOUwdme8PSk7g1ty1dUyREx5k/5LMb07j3kHkYzKvUJC0/DeKhjTXQyjaKQDZmbhsRtBLDgKH@KrAG8GXt99sYdsmjW6dAMXGegg7DDMWTRxgHMV@MBxOvS48xESWyCVqJBYqBnMkCljuffBSX0QaegTFS9b046Vg@kuaKmodl/kctFdgQMPAgPekhrWQlwGmfYN6AMWDWbe3gMf6Lu7dJrVEA@/8Zulns7DQmAYdKWWuIj/eRbJzD5ghVfYsl0SJmWmk7qjI88hDUX5Dg@caOzgz5uCKOpgm7XIhUnfjqXd5RdazTQsVQgwjkLfYnbQeNc81kmHWKUMeqGbjkdc6Lg6dlSA@kE/smbd9dJ6DHmWZzsSggrAp15AxOBnDF80eAj4wxzsmR3N5QhswY1dnf1vifhuSpQ4iHHc3/0EpzQ/SrdgTFkypgsdHhMZ/SqXCpO2vNHKtOq2BXeMIelUjQHAA8KAB0fo3bJZdFRaAUNWimZClQS@npOBx8frSGr53S9AW7KRGXrOP93AJoKzpypEozpIEmJwELfDX8lxIhbBdSFdcB1ylaiQ/IQa2kwGezo9UkMAS2o1Kz6NDqRHBMwnKq7uyVRG7OSdJcBXyx2YnoGwC6RkIFODfQVJ2OAamh4DWIdjMyOBVLv@dem45hAIOCZARpBNMbAZCM1HRjeTEeGuiiHBEfxhThqA4jOGvA6St7aLqhC65kyTSWV70Bl@HCJOkNXaA3TzH@d0TPlW2XdrkwzoMepVWW9X8mlNjdSqXVnQ1l3UJN5@hRnoO7WQVFq6jCgm0Akbd1Wy8DPoFhV1p3yurGnrHcq@Q1KAa8wpLyFBD94Gf123bjLrD8FRSQNPiMudJR1j2xrZHU9dwf4YQtZz6SBZ27RSARZ3cTs161UCnHQ15uIwA@Zy/MUdUmX5xma7CoL3TnTG4jmNtdphDWxYHOUE1B4i4qGfiuP/ZbYD9UMIkfmuzaXha1QrXjGX@NOUkYr3KYXH6zIsyGPFyxCTqPMFUJG4cZNgIATBYiIr2lDVUGY/Pa3idw2Y/Kz7U3FTT0rZMupZCEHw1oYjyaeg46b2ZBH8u3loXbNTC1Z7xoF/fvGm6s3b36qXipslyUTB6dybkt@z3bz7HGfHZZf8WG/zyeR2MhIicxG7ulOJvPhwwfQ5uFTr@pVEB/8o9a1ZKOu7DBW3dnZSG8XN9LPk80YYqqSz6vnLMMuLcsaep0OfN0@2b5VEvzz7BnlBcNl@GfcT@QvHMELRhG@ic@NZxQS7HLHMDZSW/nnThlQ28XPJsuBE3@L8M2xQoEd4eev/4@//tO//mP6@1P6/geDXbGP8LnqMvwn98dOzG2gu9X9iLZHQG2vkFwYJpOFzeT5@yT7L/ZZY7nqs53//Men3yf8RDWfeTeCp5/4PrFdTHAnOOBtM3i7TlQTexht@y4xzVQqFXDu/Of/DdJXvwI4GDLdg59qIYC1PU1UtQol@ZSoboMjl89Dvv/Pz38uJaqTxMdELpdLTOmvmcjm8FN8mnvKGDgy8k5Rdt3nAb6T2Cfwy@Ry@cuoPmPVjVUbevchH6hX5iZmo5I75ComuIEcnxMPDclurz3/cMiYCV0tfkql5wsEfzn3fqZr8NFFM5jgizYJipAoVtJNnn3Iq4mYY67A4S8TZQ/fPzOelAhMJmp1o9uYofplIlfcOn0@efSHRUgHRExEtAszZ/N@AdXDFxY0evY58aTED5XKmY9/r1r49@Yc/35XMceewWcN/ugfPuEr/q6Rj/CmKIuftd@juUqJeqLeaPykT38j/Hvh4F/re/x7@RH/fuLj30Ub/85@gn@rCiMl9vb2EqnUGaiGgmcf83kLX11vireAdxHc3@mHbZ1unz6XWEJrpLS7u7r@fpIql8U/KE3l8A0/3AVoNe40be99NZWqE3r1qsBzT2tUAVeOMv283wPAqb363p7erFarWuN9tb43m0ike/48he30OSSsNup1KXGLdVHBnw38aXv4m5flDL1iZwG98y64GDnpITwYGTHHdynxYe@DknqWepa1s9fZ3FXu6pV7Gv2fnk4gwJpkv3NH2X62n@uARGRZ8212mp1OsgP3NNcBpwl/2QE4rWx3ku1lnayTy00nM6BW/w9OXf/VqQvQXEjpT7I@As524dk7PX0F8LqQ93fwZ2Wz2QkgOclew3/WRkFNhpjo@b6pXkp1Jn8woffXc0k9m9S3k0mrUdgefn95e5ff/l5OJ5uX9WSjnMh4l5cZrh2x/FaZzHDd3TWbR68Pm80M8tHeeup5SnsOn0o1tScezxLV8rPLkob1x/lPbyYye88uq5saurdTUEl58NvLpD7zE4GEZ3XtUoIB37t3@H13c33DXeQg1@W7d2Eo/mTQi1zkBR@ImlmafsbBQNP8e/rvnP7/6//VW6bUGypjyu3dnkIfFf9U9fbu9k78VlVFES/KHvyhB7xjktu7Kjop0i246oraUO/uuB/8KuoeB1jFPPaqlDiKCA02wXO9TJZBw6usK2IR6vJyks2q5Rb4hFPXxidaz1DLtNNjvYVrUDAayG2oFKWwVS5vCfdOsVwuCndue7tc3ghjZeFFOCGS6RntMjJ6OaEiCpz7lSzOqZCpw6TSMbto8/rZcAgDu9xu9tOn0KvZ7FijZhP9Nz99uoSGlMR9HpXdAvhki58@QRtMqjDoe@2KFcZdGMLlMnl05sBZ2Nvb3qpWt7fAvV1UVY4KjKmSCb4JRMkVd7jvXXI9I7MEMKgHH3Z7lyBasa2CqrSmpsq2tpVialf8VdZUtpepbjDxV69vprY2djaeNxqREoBNunxrVHJ3lVujhAP6u3JbWAXETWPG06ebu1CIYrZ8KTWbh7WLWhPNq8syysshY@hL0kHClbPhKFmn6ZfCbqOOKDcuk8lS@TmvhWKBJZJlEU9LgpxhxV0qWQLGeFYXt4tOUAyLbym3kd9cyxQmX2wfZUEn/rSBn3q9XswXUxsghzZ2dxuNBvl@WqM09cGk2yBzNxWtntsuNDRUNr6bdDcA2dzOZmJDGtI@mZ0s6@BS4wins9bAs294rIWrwp5p24Elxht3ZHdurI4J0N@8rB0cXaTzewAyf1w7SOfP3@4ncvhaiN4peBPfz45qh6dvIcGbl0e186MvT745evsG/D3o0oBY8Bm8Mcyx2TRvxuMbfG@a9DmwPOO774zhsDmEz6T7469@8eOv/rsff/1HP/76Fz/@@k9/88s//QV8/wK@f8Sff/Tvdgv4@5tf/ov/5cd/@2vw/A/w/ffw/T9/88t/9XP@pfe/gu//FfP7K/GNxeNfICVA@8Pf/PKP//w3v/xn/xq@/0Z8//X898c/@d/5//8t/tD56x//5K/wR7z84o8A4N/@5a/w/4//8m///a/w/3/9n/72L/@Hv/3D/5kcf8Yd/@@/@Xf892/@8S/@5r/5l3/zj3@54vcX9/7@8hH@v/x78Hk8no@B85hyfa7PL38nfH4fakS5EFP96T/98V/9E@DWP@Fv/z28wX8Y9AfhSxiSosGXloo8/4CxTxlQb7LPP4VRAeT/iL7gzT7NQiPfbOD7m1/@yz9H75m4/yQOIZtbjLuOkcPc/gDi/tsQsXjcP/jxVz//8c//2x9/9Wc//uoPUYhpW7vpWlrLPTB@gYiFR8TDiNuPiQcRc3u4GrzG1qQ8ONb2cFpByqU@fACSroEL1OQNqbAJb1KuSu4cuiEhjDo2@Lg3haN5@E6krV14w4F@CrqNFA9KQdB@ilUqlZQ0qUAYRYVXTDNh1SKOUFGzrwBcTMTTpJtF0BrZZJ@gQMpK6ow1NyoTnjCFHlWCwBAh9DqTc3k5VawcQoaVySFDWAg8JX2A54dKtViZVBHcD4QCwEjtQ5YQq4LYTao/wHuFYEJ8aXL4A6BSrKRS1SL4VKiolFu6SXnmClQ4KnuKUbnRnzGc53r2nLEv5FxR5iMsICUTsfE3FcV@RvMMzyD8MrUhikP/gZO@G5ge6mlC9OF@PPwZelN6EQHgahruBoKvpiE2zyF4wkGlKFt4pDgEoFxKTMiEHtSzpqQU1W@KXiB/wOFxn71q7AXBYXHW19fBtVeVN@VTUNXZ6Krk@cYIJ/9JgSkxeXtXRm/ciGGuvyFlfuNwA35z8H@0RhskOTk2pPUkdt9JFuShpTbdLTdB2AdFo7JsEOYpiiclIn@uQNIKDmh@W0yVFDInrNKI0ByC1iK98nr77gS0vLQsp3Pbu3wiVAwYv3VLpcoPua0dCZ70PkZLxsKmLlQD3m6jY@tCglZvtT1qaeAEFWNbqlbFKhTLSdXzowtIcHHKcvmszkA1vN3ayW8Vtgr5ze3twk4@t7W9u7VdKG6ChNrOFvL53O7W1m5xd@cOEHoO7Txd2mgV9qr/aOHzX/2jZZ/lvviRqj9lE529efMT7U6qTjQtkyeUK7nCTnlaAUTIS6qS9sS14OmtBoomVo90SRuEbnHfCqAm3WrIqk/gw6QnEnsCXvAByDgHz8TC8MlpWayQoZ14vkom5wrADKp0CczAoUnD@EfCinsK0uZpjjsL25Ezi07pAg9RvIYMoB4c9hK37vkuu3D5FrF9s70ixkGf34l0MHJB3/zd4@wbzhUPOrTQmlvbD4NeGGigxRtYfn9FjLfDAR6ZMEd/bxCOBi1AEKcJeYR9@BnZrrsswg57@2ZFKV@Fh61wwY1OW0H0s5MvX1zEnhdHtYMX0jbbP319OPcoiEgF9vLo@CJ83eGhQdJCCOLbo5cv51/FA8cMa6ywk06D4IMffKbpQ099/X0QJaev7hFNPZvOgYBvTs1bTbtrmWg/@5xbCJ90bdfLJZM9cwA9GLTRHLAx7g/tuTYMj9azB1lcE8h8wuFN08wXpmwdBN4ujOTYXqG6nZALcrGync1Dp0KGy7tOObENY7r6bqMyYZusWG8ME95WeXdTeoWbn3ZzfGO@5UkvYDwyQKPNaJHcl0ZmB8YmNw6dOWjhBSnjIVvpCQ/0QufI6vVB6N24YQQYJkotw2Dw/dwPwDDjH/9@D5/nQX4LIfZidOkmnMcJJ2hYOFMjRME73BVLJ2KC5WDqWLySdIEimO7NYXj2qYWm5ukQEvTt/FAmGYY3QSDvShIugVldlpV0mtjK7xYLxd3NfDFd3C1uFWCYWEjn8uncTnFnFzgkmyvmtouF3Vy6uLW7uQXiGEILuztSAkSW1c1koLfJyTI9LaeNBiX30DKnq/erUoJPDEAXjzeNJYzQY1xk8mbxMssgoSzh7tCNSUXGK/aybDPHcrIkG6zNEsfHB9njY1nexxecxTvIynIHXwrFbHZnX5ZNCjmALiMPifr4drSNWqssW/hyUDs@Rgjf4Uu@iDBk@YqH8Bc7eNmBaA6@bG6S2ivL34fgsgDc5RgVKZXPX7LZ/QNZHnP08HwcxKvxty1C9ghfMAATHfOQAwiT5S@DRFkgg3zG44msXgTlrdVk@YS/1GoI4isqfIEX6mt8qdEHEo3gDThflnvg6I1g@C7LLXAi/8tyG1ztqQF@A3DhqTfHN2R5ysuBJZHlCcU22lcyaHPCH/IBfF68MPp@x@zxz3TEn20IOoEgazI@Om59@WWr12uNprWjL88o6KuvXhjfTcejVq8lEraa8HExFQRdDabzHxODmk3DXh70NQQ5c0HNadMkDJvG94CZ@PQwo0HzKwz6CoKWrfkIgPAZQOQWfvYH8Nw3Wjwo@FAQPSetllxGlsWm01WIcY00PVpMvUVxqBjPQD3fkksoT90uKFXjoqoVno2L8vaOXNqAp/xM3gTnRMkms4zJyUtZVkEyPpN3CnIp@eyZlnyae8bknV25JO/syGr5DhUHRb3tKpP0pJIFj0xmD9sxtjx4gp4ilIwLc@LrL0zcb9HWtHczn729dxAPTyji8bLX4wHbZzckOnCzebA3t1nZBzmRLTt4AtjE1/VJYiJVO4ZvwHBj/3ZcKom4d@VepY4APuHPnia/q76TGyyeb2EnC1i9ddr5nb29@qcG6FqVXHmagF4kXyxPEnSeYGerrIBqr1Y883uucX2ycV5srVnJct1r3RsP6tm17Vz6Vmtqd7bh@eu5nXypPl6va7nG2lr2U29P/llVbmD2qJLRX3zyDgRaGfwCknERmOhaHyCclTR@AUGuuK3quEW66XabZHucfYhJOkw4rIiKlZmCN4TwPSNKMrmTTybVZBkir4G3qDHiiKBKZZCmUKW7eVD5yiPTH4OCkS3fBbiE2XB1czsnJe6kDtqp3NqVErfS3e3dXjXov79m06mR0oLXp4z1UjDyyNASAS4urJFL06vPWa1S653VyiJq7YDGB8A1l/zojpZZ@9yFiNRe9T1/XlZxYQ7ykQh9vliX2UtVM9Vq9VKSZTkhB/PISrEAowocev@QIDNj7OC2O3boLHHpFRLMKHENpN5Qf3ht2bfFTa1Ke2AU4Pm7RGovgytcejVD1Gqf0vqvlHBc4cR5Sh@agAKKdUHGIYzJhue773feF9@/env69vSYPc@WiqUiJwUtyD9Pp3PJXBJI@xx6NuvsSEoMP7mF3A/OV@VEaZjc3EpuzqhOlxVxclVBTlDqOO9e32w06jA8aajwVqnkn@UKxdRWKbejJqp4gi6/k6iSA5qWtploJDiArR2mwgvNCOdziWpG@Od2cmrC0/gbpCkkPClRfPXhE94/zG8wtPLkymQEVut3e3fwX72rw@jrjgZhd/SPPxn4ueMR4B@jhy/8EX1i8eJxovDGD9oe/9@jn4NTjrO8DRRPfKhUoWLfN983E1JiN1lNZZJ4Sa7YOSCGNaj0bDj0Z3ob@Pc@8tgAPW0jfIPXvQ1WqMKo39zIZDKX6k/yoLPs7m4XtxPSb6H492wkDtQNGnfhlmB0hHoKW2GPWIe@K4FmqruMxw@UFpTzeCqGnynGN@natcTB0aa45VShaBu4XxAvG/b52Qm1LFGfQWKBrmkZ9dppgsE20E42cLx0Kz3BINvEQWK2LD2JQIHHAA8jt5uePR4NSTYplC7XSLOnkARyeILH19Zon6OQLlquzDIbi0mDa7TpVOxoBJr5wPQ8PGUOEk56AklemhNudY4NDdzjG95eqmMUwpMCOnXIuwF52zxBk3wVKj2PkGYcO57IAfEvPcGNf/hmVbJlZuGO3jKMgp8AAaAMigBsNdge21TZrZVKlcOTJ@U7BpVOF1EFO/EkTIbQOrj9NEhcxngWP9Qm7nwVNcxvQwo8AyAcBp@sqTCLktMbjohos@2jQQEsOlOiUNHY06cRVpWK1VEZlQjhX1nD4ALY4ADefAYAjC8CKvIXnZKcZk4qhZX9ZJbtgOIpQhe4TiNHFKnL782SntxJEvw/mmmRI@eqigLKWABRX7xVtIFkkBjJzuuwzfagZ8/vqCxEvg24twkpOvgY@OP5Y53OH7c5infSbxOBnfXgUtBgyLPi@ncGMmc84DdficPeYpMlt8mEG59Owsvjw1RQFMum2F1r5PnBRVv8CKWymVP5XcCBD7@yF9dDYaQCbSZfUPFBqTA2HrQz8NCayGeNljhp07g3dB1xp@8Vv/eZbA/gVYd4po@jPXZuDDqvLm5ycjozGHEjAMj50fVeDh1Hx6tRDYe1RqZxFdAmzcyeTsc587tMIUaj80dOCE6lRIQwDBnpdmoYlQ7wxkzTXHbx4isL@Kp/bEHn43gZYekvc2NdWZkLvERTc7vaQbA5NsG@oXtPxZlLceCJjBTYFl0CCuRUZnY3eyy/nWa53TRQNvoCYUuoseAO5iwEp3ks@O7AY4c7i@lY2jUFL3qff27m1pQm1ugnfl54hLb8rg0nRl/6fJKELu1NPYlsTVQY7aWFdz0UudAy@abIJO6KDDfWSuIQSYWmPXScjBoqoAIFO27RCfqdeQ0xtJyEfQwIzXawFRhbMZT2CXUA1PagZeFJCH9Uwj3yFTyjr7Sh6QkB77Av2GaerkDhh2KCwwzSE6z6yix0CIOkWI6Z27lArkDrHHQgLIFHLjj7YfqAu9FNp3Ij9mZrAhx2OpRXhfFmEbwUYi/YOriNBSj6GgRuA4ZLMFlT5BSATcmqzEGH6eeTc26XSJaU2CKkNEMIgtQABVWF/fitosDbNzc3Op1kHY8s3fQywc3amWHPAnXSzfjmYCgsMFloQ09YCY1cGjSha8NDW7XPJqgOVnafTvlTkrq4W33mQlG6UXTYG/Crfits/rZQaApt6Ig5m@Ub6duAzUrIZloxeYdAGEMwk/Q03U4DsHSrfZXu3nTKIoDfNwzAobLMwBONTIyCl4EXuKxhN4zh@iguw6CWfdV2bRdVD5lPCkRZ8xIGMafBq3gf0oWpjnnDaqORMVUoXMXYyKfKlLQbNoXenULACb0Ju@Vnsa1JfdqYST4Jk0PfFYwX2AgPEkm39wPlR@AxfMLDJxA@4eGTKNMg2/qkwTUv0pCxOMjceOY3iIlgpkGcO36CPwohyKxaZTkOAmNOZ/zu4NuuUOqA3vwN6rESMEZ4tx5a7KhfNhzPvNlopDI9cW8sY1DjALreIJredEI3Ut@@toeuN@Pl8IviA7zRq90X3MB5BcsYVhAxBqeXhUctewOdn2rn/b4oMEBAdQsCUQOo@YqlloOj/QoFAuPU5YjGHLG6QKZBSpYIEn6gFXHSc8LGATVigNA/LBKgCSEsaDnC/psQAu9GaLE6iKuReboBHiNKNpJ4kehsU@EipUyVFMNK0wI0geyolVbmixKEQ1XU54JixbwT9R9Hf@2z0cc7u5djTwzL@4WyFG8qeM01aAqiuRBVWbUSq1fAILNh2OYIOqgjroaKThmy2cgEowmeDxaBG0hSYpXfVnn90F402ZFLIStMKxUo4rTCmyVvFwFJOcHDZJ5INg0YQaTnAgRgZJcmM0WySTzZpFLhgoNNViS7iSE5ISQnPAmPPVmBZEMkg0FSaIIHq6dBd5k7TAZ4Od5bopUhmXnGNZqSYt/hmUmcrRN5RjKHuEDwEGrSyGftxtLc6zGkY0JrDgAy4gIAUDYMNLYhzQu8nBa@hTKKkzKQUfxNsAGXFcBgJILL/Pi8EjIZDXVBr5dT1A9A25VTdUnOpXG9Cf@y/CunA8/gm1v0zM7GzM16ZtNzf38vng2kbKyBxpSMXHYLBTIOWGp03A7UkhuXKUuUZ/DPBPa/Z64qH8WsgqvBeIDMfzwfur7hu1tbJT4Isoi/3orosydO6TLYnuPCUCNubUPcD@sk0QhK2@05lmem0Q45V8FNWi7jtuqkuN4rnK4nSWKmjg9LETRnIFRdm03LsfxmU/FMu6uWQlM2@KojHyaTEo5nwRVLD3JIAD0dKi7ereCrD8NEUzQi2YXVvlJOhyIwCZnUGAirNujzENrHK5WD@3GxiPySZVCNW75Chk777sDtgXqH9l8w9Rz4kwg2ImQMh4RLmhk4RC3FDPZQc1DaaUMVSb/@7KTs6zzeKR6kz88CmCFGmo3maYyUHS3JrrkyO54syO/88/E9j@N7fj@@NKqex5kPtSs88POy3lQiCBAxQmPzYTTSwtzaAjozqITeqEDxBI9GsUP7AjqIaQ2i1kR0vQv8kQ7fPDpWKRD/ZhX976/AIPnRY6vPQLue51OQNwO6fZsOxXvBWpAC0U9UNdw2FM8uZO3DR@YFcfHK5GPUFUBfJcHl4JldaJhDGEZH1x8HgB/geVzHX@B7Wtyv8MAlOI2u0@wqv7qKDpsd0zamZkcRMdMxuEGJz2BkRvLqcQVHQUdCz@WDOgU6KTVungyJziOVVrCMkb6OGadbiMOjWCH30Mw3YXiymn4YviCaccquwmefQeFPJhNkx5DMTg6nwyk35WKTgadAjvL@h9ckbt9/mCBAB7Gqlo6yVe8Tn2dKWKRH9AhhXH22yHSqOei23MFwsQ4/j0QPlxQqN5aoEtTyjO24VTVu3VfjMa4IeJIvtjyOJR9iukfzXIzVOLBIhB18XheyAPnAsO12W4lD5D731pjrLMgE9KN5N2dFr9JcIlDDlCTpfIvG1aRfqBIOgU/giRNI38ATAfZMv8kZKigbzlEFRkYoZGAMY1qL8AFtHKDEqBhYCCU0YrGkwA3Rb@/CPNsr82wv5NmeyTNsAbNZxiJJ7ZksRS1g9dxXBbbZ9VdIZwzCQTI87hPb8HFcY4TTErdJK1my0ix5nSyBQE6aydKRAkI52UmWDsnhJUvn5LhKlr4GR9S2kp@SpaBZYIQRvJLjOfoLEY7v7WTpQFHvJB@NuAb56slSWKcQ5xl/JYoAKbDcoDXikpnjimL6IxM6NlIq0ww5xkvjOIkmXNL0zcI/t9bIrQpDIM5ZblBklmK5mU4j1mPwfKDbCKzXLGnJJdGbH50eH@HKXWQOE8JTMJiLpyHwoIYnkrPCiCOGobRCAU9AEOVmaTlGLDdrM/UR6Ijc0fQOVvJs/kQ9nfSBjkLhdYjcUGdNcYr0QX3NguAV@Dg8MfEqPBfQCbIjjHCNVV2CFhL1Q/KeQmFdz9mZ5bUfryGau56NBNhqQRReSwQ2JtNBh6PFNsxs6A5nmYRCccufFU9Ds2@8USL3ziUjqSBa5opg8hYlQ8EQb/zqfcWJpUPUZkQQBtazDd7Kwn6BZDEGRbIupqnyxgcoxGQOtHCzfWUi2x4KJ8Xj4iZNfcWqbihIy7MkyTUrJiGxjgcfx4bPcw8Hr0d4HPLzhq9ByglOqigIIJYyzIXLV/cz9HeX6@@BQh0QYS6DZYr18q50Ub2@t5edw9yOsl2sQAxMs0N1qXIU5hCRHEYHMc38Pl5bUPFxCwdX8nmmIfQ5bT8gWzgmeIBu82MLDgu1hNH1rOdVHjyv8qsJtaiR2Nd6oLTomJOAwwseYhoV7X5cecGXVTGG0ES2YX92BY9mKzheeQiPCjCaIzlv5XjyAde2orZNZofQB0VqrsS4IKflz7CaI08Q97QUGy7Dgsdp8@zw9PXLb6HT3dnZUUUfPY3ww1aLk6phP84hT9rm0A/7gyXDlnwarQri4jXdatN3R/7apSMvyBIurEEZwM2MAfuJNq4KWRaT53NtF9LxuDGKClhXUTMwZqQSqjoGdtmWoCu/nU7ZMASQQL0FeqdptKbinCxwB96z0GxS99Vs4makZlP0Ylg1wQq3@tvEGt03HtxWz7QbSUrQBMHhKXv3onbBLl4cseO3B1@zb0/fsne11xd4rufN2/2XJwcMvkevz49YNKOAH7QDiwNKoOuh2TYHLRDZ@Wx2ixHkA3c45XJHOVC5/7kxYC/ctonrUXueMXje5y@6Y/pVnuoIhqNTnMO0yHLwwPJ9fiVCG8CRctOhEyGtsW8yiNuCMe0Ax7wDt2N1LYgr4dh3aJlecAKB4W2pDsjbjtumyxfSXElCm7S0FYiuF6CbIfBqAYiPizQAxvCiqywsjycwOzoThAs/n03Bi6OzV@es9vqQHZy@Pjy5ODl9fc6OT8/g9c23J6@/BHqenF@cney/xSCK@Or08OT45KBGHhyBrM7w7BbdFXEfCjpGJ6pEN1Rp4Vt81hmigQbPbgw6G@Ox5NhB6WMZtvXR7CTLEhqf5udxaE2AhVc/MPN7XMoM1nxpP4H81iPzyetZtke5QWOpQnsri@YK3R6ahsOFh8GUoRlts0wHrBRyR@a5aVNOxzKZfIB7TnDum5/DorYcgIaM1gA2ggo2oFQY2VlMJtN7BLIKubVtF40r8Nz4pkDxgkmfB1tHyhJRTOx9QaC4X/rEwfmgXDn0AL4Hj7zI1h/xCGwz9OAR2Bb3QFX0BPeCsIKIMfZPxyie2Tb3@G4wPKb1X7YTeuwbNIotCpx4vVGVGiy6BNsaDG2y8Mlnechct@G1LYuSeBQfLU3adnBnRssElgeZKCyc4141iCmDsOniUoPYxuaMqWFDKHAD7vsxur7HlIqqswvc7GM6Frex2rMNh29pirbiEO@xIh5TrYitzlZok5R2oA9dYkA0JzyLR5juUGiF5mPTQcr9hRwNseeRzF8HW8oeQmB/AYHfBQwA0mZGOm3qqeisE4KBiJyVFc8FjsR52x/i8YGdO@O2OZMguNHkO@vjR1UQOT0zTgr2HRJ2UEV4@Uuar1l23RG0cRKrA8Nv91EKtvvu0Ld4HSqzJYjs0Q/o8iRE8EOlOpMb3UEzl6PjOrFMW8DFK3LFiy8fkytxPF8kD8VX0NZDg/i0jw7RMVrutRlbO0vjItKNidMvoAjzyzywt/EJE65/SpHs@IEuWClWqof7l9oPH9JoIJOLBW7CPthEyC9kGWBe0DxonY82II5Q7xItLbCy6o1bmFrsqRPSElt5AAzGgX0LxnXPm@UwjG8fXvSHhrngT56fPlV4Kg0lE5fIY6@vRNItzepBlmlK02Bir0dMdgKyIOuVwCdNMEN5/RzPbGAtlIEiDsoRukpp1rqpECFB6VrjLkgWYZ5dVHcIX2VV2joRKJL0UeL1kXmv7FdSVTUT7RxhMXIqgYhOB5DRenu0/4T6qwVwh/eDA/n9eHDFe7Hj3cNnQTu8F9pn4aalVsPi3VIM1uPB/nAPWN65/U5goezp1YB5J7kILeT0kDnT64lwd@z9OX5YqDtqewAG@16cQQmBxnIbO7REHRhMUngCNQ4mUojOLw6Pzs6YzMcnkBbkHg4ZOkIMIuw19ibaPWs5JOz0UGkKB8uh8hT4zGxdCz73NealxFshKoQOkhb0CIXF7MUwJPVEz0IqBO2mJ4EYUG4Wu9tABnl1AfgOj96A8EpEalhYQGlpMRO887G8@KZuQbc0143je/JpxzTvu9Eq/GgaBxTf/GP08KTI8vp7x/XjUpAPV7DM78dU4A5o0njLkc7OIeMh3iGvz9bgPdUSVClumucKdiKgHe7wys5q2L8/QxEjcSWc68IxsS6UY4Ea14/XAzWHdh5iN2Dglk4RyHcoQ0Ag4slnL16hatTpKbNdECiZaM77eZwrIHnjrhzeV6RE/WQlVMjjbW2dsKkHWDZwdlbALq@O9AXubd6eFw/zWYG0vTcr7e8mK95LzOQU0HxpYYJAgLxdKGw@BHu@FEFy7feFzfuQefnpD4Ywvo9AelOPpveBc09ep4PwiAHuIR3fKh80mLmEoOos6VNmyk6dURw/wIXPCwEyaMqs3Ufj5bO5qmwyh9ty6LxHikOnKAtliDXhsKC81SxQ/@7@7FAgP5jf2ufnxxsbRsI9gne/DQ/XxawAxLzwcOesnzkaORSNH0sauHh8jE4j3Xtmjg7N8Q2tvDAYSMts8QJ0xSEjvq02HUwxUCY0q6jjZQc4qVeen9XTcuV4CY9PXh6xDTLf0p2ZgpRHshoTOWuWcx8CJHppOgJ7DTqK94VXgi/gkA5AApnoUJ5CtFEfxI0oAspynSydim2fQqTm5iu967UNpwv0TMt0q9lTSEiTr0enx@qyCfVseSY9IOcNHQVSpWVNlykp@NHNGgBpFgSvTfSP9VNSJhOeLrrn5icjkytmt3fJOgRz0n56UN9tpDfaFZlBn2s4A288uulc9dz@dZfZbPhda9KefvyescIWwwO7@afc0lNuu4JnZBW2A79FtpslhhUIPiOrVZcyY2QqBU1UJVk0/C6voaEk@NBYuYQnIOa4lG0MAi7Ek3J@ZVDfblScSrY8qDuNMp7V81MVP5VLKejxFDpPEC18Qb7uN7Ar/W18ttV0rhnebAyjpPDsB6OzH9i/4wyX2LNN8@W0zVh6gpvV8AyJ7pg3SnhJHXKmhPqP9IQO8eTwiDZNF@NsS8cCDID6aVBWvQn9TlXpSVYfD32XQkRGGrIQ@2R9kp4Ep46yNGEAUepWI0Bnj@BEcRRc9@G@U74bWstxbSyHRx3VGIg6piRpJ1/KMh4BRETF0at6Q/J002j3EQm84OMTJWN7e/yewjsIpkk63KlhjOjgQ7aBTlzfgMeQFhMwC1LMPTq@IUHx8T2HDu5DU1A@nXehje4SKYIYgtu42S0dR6L0e0AATvgnXKXSxQymUKxAT@RH/WjuAI01zY7rcRUBT0HySnmChUXYPL9KBJx2fBONMFtBJvB/coPk5LSCjyiBlqO3hWKE8VUenUhCy9DizUNaUpVSUBUfdpRMiSXTgmRB5BgpnjxIDZzIgtHPKxOaz5Qd0E3bOU6LJxE50EnHcUX@qTB/r455NkLkebi2EK7NhOs8nCMVxdKh/44ileKR5MRtFO@OyVG09EJeFUa6iQ413dZB44jilu@L6@m@27SiyNWwKjlXhgF7MwFaLOT9ktrnIWszaUIGD8PrPFzwd17UfIjlTNzns/njUxIVZNLeWLGVZI5Ldcey@W3bUQiymczw4kueHOub2I43SnFkUogTUNBwGp@abbUSQUnlAolDbUau7j2XdaFMPFPm0eCHDhca1pI2EqMS5Zkiwk3ofCHkQ8FrMRAEExmNBS23GiSeisTTGFiMtRZkyw8tLjRwKNp8E6/gMcZP@BM09lnkgniJ5YFPOOYTXnh@GHmWQCR01@TlZJqVJnjsg3uKQt3Ti0R5T@chLhcSr2OTvGGeJj8y3cVZ7rVQTsQFRSApFugehghKRxFyAfuuqkIMvJN@m9mQvjRAhR7a5oTVcBRh0GkqaeY8Ol4v66EVHTQXB8Pz4dDGRUVS7G7oxLMw4ZEv4GpKBDG2jKZLJ7hxh8dPo0ucH4dEOjtFyDcWv8ZVBHh42Tddi8nw8iwQrTihYvm6VHOmfL4C2sxmnp8KFxf9ogC2rV4cCV5zvPWEV7DqkrhJXeJF7fL2LabL8VgIXXbudkuS9JOx1b46@BKXa3dy2c1cjGTXYrU3q29uxe8qDwPyWVBXC7ktSYot/bb50q@GANPsJXb03wBv4h25jinVoMegiB5e6WuOrs2OLklnZrjGi3CRlenWW4d57njU5nM3oFvhpVh42tdL89Uu4DB8Yv/MV4PbtBSWlnBNKlpMpntO8Trd8EBJ18XFX1qPwFP9nB6YaGD6QJQNlc2iREvLAhfSXQZjupQYKRpfegjJ4Li@1YaaoYkqyQZQfJUjyozfURjDBPJr2wYe8tWXIYCnXyIKBAgEK0X34SCJNfHPwiG4lzRYQjeCmsmA9HOprQzwznMLpG9EYKoVShbDHSr44sXJOTs/Pb54Vzs7YuB@c3b6zcnh0SHb/5aWsHEdnOwpshenL0G6hIvlfFH8FDzk2jmklClAqr3@lh399M3Z0fk5Oz1jJ6/evDwBaAD@rPb64uToPM1OXh@8fHtIi@sAgb0@vWAvT16dXEC0i9M05Rokk6J07PSYvTo6O3gBr7X9k5cnF99SjscnF68xM1y0r7E3tbOLk4O3L2tn7M3bszen50cMCyYdnpwfvKydvDo61CF/yJMdfXP0@oKdv6i9fDlX0NN3r4/OGO0BiJVy/wiwrO3DUBVzonIenpwdHVxggSLXARAPEHyZZudvjg5O0HH00yMoTu3s27QAen70k7cQCQLZYe1V7UsonKQ8QBWol4O3Z0evEGmgxPnb/fOLk4u3F0fsy9PTQ6L1@dHZNycHR@dlJr08PSeCvT0/SjM0pk9ZAwygFoSDe//t@QnR7eT1BfQZb9/gdgYVKvkdEAawrEHSQyIw7nLA0gKRTs@@RahIB6qANHv34gj8z5CmRK0aUgE3TBxcxKNBhkDEi3gx2eujL1@efHn0@uAIg08RzLuT8yMVKuzkHCOc4H6Lb4F1INO3VGqsJ8CLO4FZpYBz01Sd7OSY1Q6/OUHMRWzggPMTwS1EtoMXguY6WmuMTZZYLs4NGIP4BEp30evabEP/uTjzsnwuJjRwdHB6eAQaH7eCJUf@b6HTKc4ZPoqHQUcTBsLrjIGZjtka95p4YTgeFQ2T8fmNgddLo/VmFUbn7FK6x4C3mEahBIlEs/lNrQnj3PNmU00/JuUMGg@lEJPc98VSRRltlxtvwPmdUomTfW@GUNWnYhmTtuHh8gLG5MR/yje2GQNTZZlMxxTJ8Aw@Ag5miMRl8H1cKAHJSEcZ0QBzlCVNQNC7JbiBEioBeL3dxFlQ3PdIkVwPfpxP0QvvG2IeIJz5rFYmg2NYQsP6aAbZ8EzIsgH9CMMCVpey1D3TvOop2Xh2OOTXe67bUVQ1SENxfRgG9hT1geQtszeXXJtPT8jSonJbXP0ZDLtJgwlXlwXJmKgXfUQlI1tuTW7STQ2w4aYbcE6UsqKpaDE3qTzlyXG/UZoJCxV4eIIqGVW@V7WfnrzDwVw2v1We838R@vO2hbsBR2PSL@uUrkGPFw0eARoYmdQAkljC0EUmE0sT7CYJI99AxD5GurE6uK8Huuq@Sd06kAT02DFdWBulh854ZE3i2IMY/vKs9mr/7fExSE7EdqtY2NkuS6GRrJ@m@fNbzIfMSJKNsCF046CmUVCslRyA3kMthWfBzU2F7E8MnMlgRLTUG1QaeaK5hnBXxuw@JZRjWFwPrZE7uAFPNpEOMr@6eU0K@HVpyxQMoMwUVcXS4L33qOEboCoRD4itKvaUam2CPwg7bP5BEw8LJBhIsJg5GPpT4FwYXJDck4@DjaA0tiEzOxhFlwM@5kbXQhrQTBftjsWzs/QmeDtWix7fqIjtlaqdUgISa/NYsGDXhMNb9hsyFyLmecnWF/j8VPAbOL8V5ujIOJ3h@TX/HMh4HKbE6ehozlkUui4gN6oVqKKnT8Oc9hhO5qsCKWp7YtY4tO8Raw2ESgO3DFbYHOByaA5kPkva3/o8qbJbzqlogwPhlAXHinfg3GXFEVDKgRkQ8R4Yl2AcVmirhFPtJsxDCqJ8G5qjCMg5Q6bfix4E/x@QJkvg78GAE6BH1IqZ7HsUJQkqpxWMXoko1k2wnhBbxIioGff6NgJzF6@YflgwsUgz4adngASidqaBx7dkpLCrLCEAMjnOa8Tbb7jhrG/AyOm5rIrkuBzitAdDhYm@IugqFuA20qRzpYMFFHxRmconmmLZvYSE7DnfI@eLARdIsdaUfeHJHEYqpwa2OzIbNOkRtnJizT7fiDrPTlnRtILGL8wkxXqZTmjtCFTRu5UrchssZsVyRuCLVS21HLduGS@wIBvkWUVEl5Ybd@Dzrbiz1hK5jd4LsmDnGV0aM2NXJMzNtWjTpW0inC86NDOCF1v5N9hd2Bw6mdmLoDHlC9oUgplEOwwjG4EofFUdqE6d7E2IPU1TIr@G2AfXy5t8iiuIoXNjHgLD@NF4nb3iN83bjyu3HGWeQrJWZ/M/Ce6r5z3l0PVo5A654Ej/Cy@iSLANB/qhiEpi/6Uc8Kh1o1kTeFBemih5YMQRxgxkYHKZ0n@3ckBA9iVnV0iZfOmEk0gl3pFVvgjUF3Txthu6vkWXmGeuQKEAOfDB5VShBiHKqDfhEt5iayP80DbcO8scdeLTctCbdowhzgCR@u3SFfbh7JWwINc2fM@cghbazliTDMFoKl@5fad54NpGz3ItA8YKaM16whsgOqfkRPufvZF749FVBhTQiUXqTCM3t2DCLXrhe7g0Vo5ZefJ8c6jEV8T90bTW54YIaPIWt5mxUGaSEdXhvLmtMM1WIUokzZ5wpB1fObW8Mu1mbllivniMAESzqs4t1vNTij4dfYkdbywvRGjdFyGGY4tpzFBX7AmbwXgXSEQrATMYB8gsrIDHC4Gjg5UY1zuTdIfM2Y3QlI95aKJdfk8h77SBl0WBpH@Gi9IllitmY0n5RP4ETdqhY7qa3Pmdf2DsAYHfA/3c5jJuWcYIZNC3G9jz8bjOLOxSAi60AQ23VaZxJACDZHdk9WBga88AbU7moc4GT1dRgzaZQNcsLLYtcCW2SAWUb7w0R2mCyGlOVfbpE0uypEqWIbBHrPlKdjXDmg/t0KTGj@uIfPIGBdOBgKzEkF5FqjZQSb7MynMbOOMocyu8D7eYfP6xtTZHwMqyTU0xQ/2KHPSXdMZB6Dy4suKOQBjLc9QTuw2Snu8Ok4@k3krZsdTI1zJat1X1wa2mnNkqk1R@o0OkrUzROS1L8/jMMc0sxWhTE/AQDqHIHbL5PBEnlSa2t0pz@gAdVtEs2qITdiphfXd428dO8Rr3jAYdTdikCHe0d1kO/etNKHhztQQRMLmK3ySJ0USR0ZxyZwzUHJlCKj2eQsR9Avc5enSAcphvB2gXr5@VRJ3fjxVYzwyCZuwlIj3R1DceCwS5NOzi@j8aIuNLJKGQ4lbNzRIadqXVpJzWQnu1GMAB4mEVU4vmQvgsYlRZc3xE9uS7ShM3rORQEoGrGl9kD83EhwQjO@5igkEsujenWq5R5pAmISTQZSnWfZCCE83wWm9OCMoCKaCJLyFFWKIF2dR/fKl@37JAPIDAU1Ow2EuaTWNhVJYCbOAnHtScoA4cZSVSzrSo2YbQJNEAbQGGIT3b5KMn1P6sEed4XGAXzQhUe@6t4CMlUqAB6O1sSG1MMulMMYoqyM1bm8q0Kk8SMRR/R/KLpshVXRouAQCTYwzpKzmAgBYyCXucmCbjLnHOm0FU1BEkrOSwWYInGdiMthQuCUeiighbhViM7LIYu3EY2lIgoFgsjxMhglc5L40SQYGObikusRg7y8sTxQCFOOB9TnGoClErszQMa44TEJyEbShR6jmWzgoOpsCtgjoTGPI3he5mY6HZ@VCgT4hhXcvNhxazM6Ez2ebzs0lnUgI91HiuM4FACjWOcCgVfr8PHX6IW88OtyXGBhkzWobYCuzgUOoGx236dx7bo2O/gY4RwIufPQ6GX01@KceMfe/7bXkzYSm@/PsXNtgbGSAijMuT4bPgNIXCx4OksMrY02OpcKAbmHILT8AHQ1q3y765OD6esSvamgZbXQbmqJDNZpGHW3Ez6sEuXpy/sNzMbOxMd2zbmeHNV6NvWhkS/XhrqO25pWAAbUKNQJvwdHfU41cJIA4QFWNr4qQkDvXH3W7cZj8ukmHdQa3xmOK4PaP@xwq3XXxzQRM8BFL0rx@wgFi@DyxsfDcG1zMFlGAlBFLjptRrOVjAAfKgRxd3AoeLJQQM5XKwnwa6LbVSvcUOBK/CoMoiQ7jqbbRBVn5h2rabZu/wWnU8iv7kbj7B8XE8QZZHwUUuOj469sjgaZqZ15YdO7iKUeKsjuCCfim4mCCwMI5W1s/M3tFkqMj19zL0KlDkFBYzhZaO00zuyaowO/4IsJwPAe1HxR4YQ6VNdJqPDD29aMCRCzDazKWXDn1moqh0xYig2cOxkajL0dXJGgAUXSVVILCKTtVLJVkRPSSufDnJdZGGWQ5D4IRGPR6XAs8y/cNJxWu/232cUCSD8rxi/4sLRJqRphYomh/QE@0xf61Bsz6es1jB9Ru89mFR7mCCJiaQpC/ale9vlFqtxtaHqRSr1fbBoWmstl9jh@ixv88O4X0f359W8oVCmcvcQ/UWPPcDzzu2DzBogjPV7o8O4RXCKngwCfcLYxWvZyrr6fJ6s7JXLXuZem0fz42Di18Sn6mJF7w9PrNPL/X3YSRd1zPr7dv1p3dlfK8fNpLrrfr6sJHslZHLUNy/HXmGbcQ2MOpt6YFDOh3baq06uBPu4LA82i2IO/YU@KlUYAT26RN3XfqRcxQ50SxnlNywh32DkjOCUK0ka8mnT8G1V0n@LElzJ8LfCP0/gj9TUZbTuX0iLV49w2rnBycnccvXKPVJe@@aaKZlZIYmWyzHs6BQH@iQIRog0OpM11lDw7v@BHq41aDJI86iyIeZHJkfBJJB6WhfCK2fimEDLozS1DefkefrJAOvR/pdMHXO798yxEjli06JL@oQjBQIPIxf5tulxdFLLD6gS1dTa/XcdqGhJRIJKbyTq9kmMUe5DSmv8I6mYBmX1mD4SaAhNBkou7ibGmgBAJEYiQTd2PS0zW8WUxwcWtOIiQ@4E8mYPo/zTVQQKRRzfIabn@dHHQsHfHQLFvPGdBAAdYPpY5eUAAE64bVHgovRvYqyNzTbVncaLrvjpQhR7tBX4qmtDdZdOLTF5FFLFuVa60YAgSCoBZC5GAQ6D5ATz4W4Fkk7XsbgHdSNRab6IOxPsy2q4HBTytC1pz0bMlNoO493A9IJKK@KyrKd4DQX5sBTtswuXpbMWzSvsGg7KeLdMnEqwmnDALODVxTZaBaKK3x8CZIMIkJ7QA1HXFHWxdMIiu3wTSxuF5zQ4eNBLn4dG7FhCrtUwVA4qMXBcXDFmZADG0NVZUMeE6kK79ECMLEHTUHSeFjctTazFDhURUr03ROcNsTb5XAgLcxTqqIlydRWwgVY0CoHuECGi2NAFIyp03VWIBqm7IPtfAjLz5fUPLwRj9bP@IVzlE2er5GDxAqzCU5sU3Z8O7rMJ1fp8ivH8AV5h67nWS0glj8Nqoms8PH96yOAepmUeGaCW3ChDgmMXhvDsEXFyxewkjkZ0hFxju8TnNp1Ai6YiYjLirgmxteGEzMrxY7raCRyW6ZvtfkmPp77WiCLh7hMS7v3CbHVGcHggS9UBhVMOVwGBm7EGiVVdQSH6IT75bH990PV2yCaiWleIaLF2QVAKGSOsHYuIyJFEENOIACzRBE40hZkQcEnM4xpmz3Ln0mTFkYA@M5nXoq7gPTYyD8gwnHqzlEW9@pTq2zF@pkPgt7B9gAUvEEYCNqiKs7fLuO9oDDYq/G7D8OUvEh0pKu4yB@hPArQiWMNLRjIh803PVtD1LliX0d2zNCaZGeWVVlUC/fmQMAFilxebNAZEwIgpMU8TbQ6UCM/Rw0Qp3PNIJLC2RnwMQZG5o735CSj5sjLq4urBAvCO@CXAFNkgjspPFVy@/ed70xVtkZ4RBYaH8RCPoA@OtrmEJpymAe5tAXemIGiLuyzgWgcjdEoGt8@IXoUtKJi8UYayzTEYy6roOiihjXSlIZkogNe68l4Xc4lDcobpW7MptaS/FTRbXC2SIlpOkNVHDkSoU94Z57bLgRw@aEhWnqjt7vgdJM4HBTumQhqR5Cculeji@TBXRh0zU9YOXfLWCMYwwdSPiiz0CxAuZwBTrBoiUbEi@9EWUIkvlehNvbdE//vXqcn88ZirS/0pBs/QS8wQA0WKoKhZoQLnLgDVv27GhagHLBAEPA9VIZngluSuOYhRpjyK6@3706UbPpSvpTTue1dVaZxcqiHJdoejIzw7mcy2IW3BoqxJxkGpHnta5OL8FHL6nRMJzAHCklFbmFQU4Ct43T@bSjuPH7JqkxC3JRjstzToBLJQ9Ca3MOR0RsY5HztXoyM6Ql0QvR66vD6PEd4Z9AZ4bVAFHLG22itA6qGfIfj5IgnHlVEOrJkgObT9kk14MbgYurCEgKYCwTgeYbl92YLGyNDvPx87iLUnqnfhEr9wDUUj2/k/cAXTj5I/M7ZAV6K2uR@wJtK7FJa4aSguZuShY6AAcEes5gvT8FVfRtXekxnZh0isF4rGI/fXMxTpZkNDJoNhlz3F8Xle3I/hNh7H8TAxm/3m4Ox7VuiZAvFCsqFieav36Xh5P/X3pc2t7Fsh30mfsUIfLrCRqzcKVAXJMFFokiKi0iKonGxDMghAcwIA5CAJKbi7KmkUuX4xY4d26ksdlLJ1yRlx1X5Cc//wb/A/@DlLN09PYMBSened997rnvtJ2K6T5/eT5/TfRYZMXlMCF66MgyOndYPxHtmwS71ZBkiVN4oCCFMYtHkRznc1H@6dvSYBiGqsOeJ/DStj@zd0j1zw9z9shQ10DGE9mAjhVPsZ0QTN6D0UsQ7Zw3V6yc@4QPbAYOCzUg4FPuYSPOdPsc4w@i6goiJmtwfQ2b/bRZyOYVeG7xRknIpWr8Cy8A0zJP1SbM9ZWTFI7Ym1cJK4eDXdtsUkq0QJzThVQtcxv4cf@0C6wOSm4/704ZKag7rvMsT30bzMYdSZVMbTsXE0MmszwL1VWdGdE6CSI4jbPN5nAWmOzaMDiUbLJQAJLc5yGRLjkn1NIS8AYqRwzOl2IiRrLjk3hQHRKCwphqSqIrTzTvYRNBrvNXzTjDZVj9PqbPshneAejxriBCulsGDA2WODlTu6waK2xU2Tpzzgw2TfwD8o3QXiYQtX0U6hGqWvteVFcsIXaKBe6IY4QCOEEa31kK/dV7DgugwaLzg7BckM5wwShdAFv28MGtYV700lnpYgHQDVsvqIo614vtd9Os6CdxVBP6HPnaBSrXxQsd3AwIsayaigMhGCUeDxlvdRgireSMzGY8InaHMJEeqyc3l4lTJI2pCI9Dvwd4zGcSnmOaIARYeKMRyJIyKMGJ7@PSjs27MtbSvf6FX0kCRvUtpJs8Jx0Fl8oduqTOTwptCzAD0Rtz4ygtquivJ8xmE9zyZycgENIE5DXTrBpVR6aS44HVN6IZyCsnXuZ4aFsuH8qL7N@n@W46x1FUQK0AxCFnJHSB/RlGIeYIFh0DGlLRBnz11n8FQK1OO0Fo8Vo3YRRpa30qWJ3hOHNWhF0JqVuiUdg0viGe3p90qht6ayhsiYzK0mBFDL5d4m0FPR2YdL8LVLZUb1@6DxbVDBnCLoNDQLDbWUyh95ErvzjffGKJtdGUd4DFCBX3fQHE7fIPxvsPEObh0gQhhIg28OFJgmyiuzwm9f2AAAeHtzm/CGREkrx4f4t3QZLxx73fUyIePDhW9b3zIGMIOGLnQmBBFVe5HvNZEvnRAg@P5wCKlC73fnlX6RTPx2KUqQkePW4t8Fs/l@CzWz56hm8HbBjx98K9VZ1tTMm70zh8joRsAT/D5S9cU8A8vULJX6ClDdqD2bi8uwl1PeHJd2u1VOHK3Ir8oxwmVu0YDjmMgtmTZlAI5sUc6SIY2zlLBlozcv@jAlEI6Vy9IIYiY2JSgZCZKe3KZQYKZJv5Ky3gaqaYwJZ4AdKReRNaE@HRl19k2HQ4ozG@SZTrJtTkWi1Ag4oJn@ClM/Caa7CmvKXYy98BIVES1og@iPdQJ5rFWutXeo1gs70mOFfZV8PrgOnTTEWPry1myx/BliUfzZZMJutNOeOxZYtIB3qLwlTh@XD7Nu6AFPFHV8ihuVLrAJ5EDhhgmqIUaxt5lvqBa@pPb17N9P7Evv6kHQ@I3nn1JqOGv@5mYhMfE1EOZGA9AlKrjxRuVU/BEHmDbdkhCTgi2h@uz/fXBvpH12aH1cTBww4MThW2qFpNDqu3d2qKEWqiiQrp/DK0IaS3v6e@iYm9/Z8RGNzTPt3cMF346hv9@H8MZNRbo8PKBk0ab@p/m/u/D3KMLxdZ8dj5b@cHefVVaVF9Y0cB7q2FEnxi55Rdz7wdr2feDhendD5O9yeV85rgLf3uTHyZn5yf5J/yAr4L8uplcnnyOYLN3k8NMsViEnwJLaR2wLL9UOBFq@Bz@WZ6ReGeHk8tTRSr@eXJ5Fn7k8nloyftBeeH9YD6L/4su/SaxH/rrimI@xmF1yK@KOBD4LVCoyJNYbrseylXtdNjCJSDFcf8FKZ78gHSKGozKM4P8fFbwKrCA2P/DjSlCQLVNDN2lrqfIh0mP/GiwxYX0/yB09bgQ7ABVRRz@UBV02gvWy/M5Id1NIJfgNdr47ml6Fp@uvxNuKFQDlOMJYjNZlRvEixhVjC628O9y9kVUOaZYjAq/FVFd41@8bYpTcb6gLoonIkZiomQ8axUKPWXUQqZs1c5Fv3phPvPFNjQSCD@1drC7@qp8yNqFpGm8uruTxqwDWD6aONAyq90W8mK8qAAK39cPV/fQq8bR2h6VOSarDUrFR7O0qOVnW41FA9uVrqdujFy6gE5QZzLZ6UxuxsjNL2bnFvOzQDDNOgYPdsSvn2FRg7o1EjxzZqKEMJi3zeEsF42NvW0qgYFk4e9a@fWugYFT0zKV0/3eNld3X5c975nHW4eb6OaQXR5Kr5eIgNwUNtG5PA9Y4CzqDR3TDTmibNQk8qdXu041A@xkILmDgXbMHuT40/sdC6gcpQl56KCkzjFAD0dPV56AtPUmEsB0oR7JZdadM2b6Jx@z3ZknRn1659mcUc/udArP54xWVvyf0ZpuF/aNJ0@eUBCcSVQCbUYeS3W9Nm29K0/EZqeNBHkQi3s5O7t7E1n5NXG8fziRU3n7axN59bG1PlFQH2X4mlZf68drEzPqa6X0amLWK7azOjGnvtbKqxPzmsPHnYkFD@fO2kQuq9gFlAcnyNglxsEvAAj2kp6LMWPxRyAZBiLmc7VmJBK3lzarNtSGAeiG@RC0BPdBTWCQnTMcVyDFCRtY6kTbbPN5EAkNGaKdB9ihCeyQZHF80UMmRp3SCLuYp9IahvzLEMIseTbyBGLxhmbEgGPqhL3Jo6AA3NPO0fY2V@YIIYAgWSKIhuC0UUBtU/B37Do9keDk8LTQXMQ15ouU3e58sxkJzqZgnCYm6oDAP7oUvhn9EKUwWh/iJadEJOkuoTFUS/AzIs5IDOU3fJqvU4NIexMjilAPAQMeHb4a4kadxUojRtlswv/5syG/3vf8n13/J4qm9LjKyLlZjI9bWkTYuF/dV77McskJXDHJJIWJaC0Jb/0t9dZNb6Ke6wusZxkqypJmIn49h68FfvnHckmqEU5FAEEEYsBo@CbuIl7ThALtRCaBojM5gW9Kh4BAX4S@tnlLQjVQ1mBDA7OqdqGazgm8dVsKEGSR1UTT/D75iazAN5JHWMnAksM2SRkyMzeLmXiDlzKQk12KBGlqxerAysWIQJImyqUAm5Fmf2eNZ8i9tVBsxXROoB4D3VukCQNi8Q1u3xy/RKs7Z4ICekhQMmYKDgTD3V9uf42KJXi/4LLE0o8pubW@KNcRlxbuSibEsKoXftldSlz2gEbwC2Q2XRRtrYtnfEImdEfFotTAyn64qSlNy@Pu4U6Ug7148sW9QLI8thflR3bj@/UCjjVviUAvgMTHAC9KXFLs0lDkw1DAWUgoqDdfhwIOUG8twR73IXhEeThyvfJTX14eDunF4FaGfYvP5kQVuIj/s@7/bPg/cftCShUDcuSnjc9GDX/lZg18OYdf8/CjwbTSX7Dp/6QL/qJhyjJNRYG5BvQOhUrcBCbuCwLEGClI2rU6lWa1bbXQf0xpvbK1Uz705yK@tFsRDb/s2Z0W1RH3g4kGYb4bw4@4alGsSdFyid@M7XEdKRrPysHhfrn0GuW5OMazkTsgyAPAP0HrEW8doxsau9MBwQcqShmxg5KRiBvfYMuUnhp@PLoKviRojK2x0XfyVJXQaVff/p00KfWQRjiamBGLG5/fv4cjNTtn5NrO50K70JkrNIxhYe7Je2kqo3gQQeUlgdnhralcpcAOa1b7rd5iaGVX2awx3S0YPfMSOO5BtjuKX@gf4X1RQgv6LTwbu0vGbbfqePZreC76WZv7uUi@BYB1gKm4jSENj3MKPp0k/hyXJ@VKBovb4gUSf2xbHuJo/W2Z4rY8p0pH2/BLq03LGsSliPh5WXUvQcCIsF9Cp8fOgkXmLt2o7WFSNxKpA8Ph6uE3YnbtClZpfDHCMcqbRqWC/hIqlZhrtpopEaciReyyK8DITZmJUdo4iEVRQPkztVif/gzPlQyGX/EjFJ4NMb5EjGqMRFTLyIMFgmnNgHHLogKxXiEI2L5vmFZSOvZaHF8UXPF6lV2jCgd3fkdshKPvXqZCkoE8j6aqZRqSp5ZNSF7XbrXCivSdFgYhMUPyMCZ6SDIQhjE5XTQMcMNQdezdsAIcIt7LOD/TBvBMH@Dz81g8fOphX/lnPOgp6xCDCFHi5NautgSBuRQrUJvryTW0669bqBEcRAQMNLtPwOuzQZyMLAcU80Utq7i3kshheBC9xCQQoTeKVrVda1SNwSJqgQ2e5vLz8ZSGUMMI02u1q61xOA0NKV7ujSKZNA5o7Us7SFehJleAAbxe@TS5im2AeOcVsJ174MnPnYLFyZfAEw4QB5WjFnPIlvPQLY4uHEo/QyvdpL6/8eQZBy07kYvrA/p9q5/60uqntPpxT35V1UXjzN@O86T2vQgJXh/lBv@qimSr/bXFv6jH@qoxzesxy7dm2y2tGhFFzVetQiMokFpTsiuEHhMeSSQQl47oC@gLTR@Tu9DS3vmToEB5sgxTPG83kG6p1ngKqV2p4NtApUKR0ioVvFmqVKJcAx28eODph67YbJyXBi61wo9csehUNZqKTk2Rq4opCwO@UquK6J6pa1bQi2A01QBBqRglglVBmEuz5RSju9RUdJpHpaPj6yhpdUAHH66EgLiWLXK5Ccdwn628H1FdXe@S/Ygu2YHKUI/g0Z3bp9rwbeW@mjAfLfVFRavwjRHcURUCg9KZbr1rOfJt4lZG9ZIh3fBKXzSB63Xppg9fa0STWGcS08Rc39rdxrZFUjXd9kVt12mke4NelF3gxOLCM1JcOq0kzRtAsBiIGR/dQ2flpoyJJaOGsbtvDsGONpqiYWnRU229SwYNSiC3pw60QRrVfLrsbFG2NyXvJl28xgw01SMstkNRVaN7cDDBBOzZDvy7JY8L@L1mer/3gY5ikiR18PslbGss0RQ/9nmvwq8de4qQwfKOnnuRwKsDq93Hixv4xeey2UkJTs5rFh752BMv0ttiZCTyD0GkW1d94C8F3ngyuhiFrrtnqKiO/xMMdbrdmIkhfDx9aQ4aFsbYi8VTudn401wufh4ZJbLiidTHOoQhHYRiTP0AkxT3O@d2RWugbCpqRJkJobK5RTQA1NaOJDEGBaT2pdl864mIoCcpVd47rzSXSkWfeMEPdwlujFeAb5n0oIfsnm5RsSDejOlQzLiFtJui6o5ruI5BMmrxyD2S1G@NnKRPyW@oqPTrF4pGRJ9fsShzjwjzxdLKDygW/MTQ/8TQfwVD/4Nx82NY8iDK0R0fYNcfZMO/nP0imjdkV4R49Zb/Gj7sB2IE5r6ID5CtRj3m8bzAw@ezRJPXj/WvPKUjv8wcNmaP1@1SqXTYznX3N0oXpcvS/il8r2S3k8dX0ytrtysbK43S2trFy4vVHfPNfGl623l1Mn@60fz4wQTufXP35buPLad@GTnZd26Pzb3bgjnvlvr9D1ubw97mylF79WDmdO42W27NNFfMD2std@314cmrw42Zg@Tth5d7Lz@2s213r5mtLrQLm69n364OjzuRmRvrqLG@be22Dxrlo3x7e806XU@uZrcPFt7kstvl23eF1dvkTDaz5bza3dg/uqqV37X2t7ZPG6sf7Orsh@tbZyvTWGiuXu2/jewW3uQ2P@zuXpTzCxubmdu1ptPI5jdb3Zmrk/29laPTzctX1XJ7feZo4eRquDd7@ebNTW8neTF9PNt/7U4nO6U3b/KvOhs3N@X9SK1qH3YL5rH9Jufc3u7ZC@0589XO5kX7TTfXyezOvE0etA9v18orrQ9zg8LR6fGb2@mD0/7rNy/f7Watg4NauTrr1Br5g6vD6Ui9XdhK3hyVj@arG43jN@2brc2Z07XM60tzp9TYa11vXGy@sw/2trdKBbffyW2v3rRONy6vXl@vrW617L3rVqc0nZlpHTZOd3cjRy@t2pq5eeK@LF1dnmZmVq6nT5MNZ@Pw6uPl9cuVg6Pd@fxgb5i1V9392mZzsLY/m5/P1Fsf9j827de5ozfJ2Zurl3nrtPSxFyl8HM4sbLdOzXbnZbJ@8W7woZVJHuVyq@@2Pp6eHmzedGulztGHt@v7V93Xjc6uu5vdf/nqda11Pd@7ct51Dg5y9eyGef06ma1GBkebLsyReVidmTtsb79xBmv2h/2td@7sx@TN8XXBXLvef1v6sJ@t3Xack05322qvZhu71dJbu1fuDzbqCzdH15ut7Q@77mnkdTk3M7NuN92V5tvphZPMRrJ5vXGykjsYZHc6@83p2e7O2zfHllW@PDn6uF@fWX/rzLd7nYs3H4/a5WR5e3D50ZzP1loHp9edyNHMwf5e/rbzymr31jf3X8/2drPbb/cam8Nc6Y2Zu@3MrQ5n1gbd2cLx2kn39Hqz42ROrQ/9vax5k2ycOr3pN1atWX9r1duvIgcvL4929t7ebs3MdjfaHWtlbz67s725unPRmH413HrdL2/XrhobWyfmiXM4e50vrxzPrp0cFHqH1696C/WbdmFvPnnYavcujpKRl/3L/tzecffD28G76VK7Zhb2W6f2cC7XXn3p5AdvS@XdjxfXe469k1vPDzNH2/Z1K/vx8PbjpjtbGibnB0e9tt07zA1mcm8ihduPTu@l8/LNwe7Ky913L6vTlnVcvTp428gWjuYz1mW3sDU7u5ErrzfbH9oLZu7j2utCtdC@TLrb15nGauPo7fF166r9qn1Vj8wvuPWVrXf9ql2u5XPZ05VmecbcXtk@zJlHF68Optd2snsnjb2jD4PDxupJ/@jtrpUtX71c2L6YPtl/u/Bq7t2he1g9tk9edXcig/mC7eZmF2ZuCwcL87uX3YPC8dVC792rq9mV1nEt93Ir3zbXre7J/HD@2vl4eXtxe2Bmaxcbax@q@80yUNKjvWx1pn@9MziIFN4etm/mnJXk6XX91Ukn15o/tuYyhx@uFq4vL1/drtWnj0sfP1RnNq7MhYP1TK21PrOR3F99s3d1sXb8cX66kV3Zfls9GZQve6eRN5vW2tXC8fXuYJh7s34wbJeyndbMzcHxzM2hvXJwvHkwf/m61m3WNq8ugTa0h0dXt/2bTXPucnA7/@ry6m01u30yv9pxp/eykZfmVruxf/jqpJRs5s2F3s3u6Y5zPH88mHk9bx8v2Lvz1qtSc2PwZrdZzs451vHh4Kh8mVlZtdrzQFP2Wkfd1d03m@@OXzrZSL4zu/Jx1Z6Z@5C8GZzOHmf2ktv90/phvn3c7W6eWN31k5u9k1cHpa3kVm24sXdd3T0tzxzsrK66L5Pr1qw53CzcuqXVQqtpR9z2ymBn0HUWCu@uty/gJLAbC42Nw8Jxxy2Vmrdb8wflUmnDrW29rA4GG805OCPwv/LxW7sY@eVH@O@6GcE/Hxv8pxqhR@9I272o2QOgl9dmt2Xb8AP@i9Raptmjf@FPw3KdCD1Q/jKT4LD18jrHcmV4CadfA2bNaNjIPKTR@ky4Hem76HFE@kNH5VOH/kZUHHL8cu1WgyNsUgDzWwtdbQyclm31ROxylEm7JjtUo8jlux2jPUR5s4f@KYXfdXQlAcesFu4c7WYAb2SiXjdyrUq10m5b6boxZasv4ztgIJzOxVTd7jStC2Nqqt5sVS9c@NFq0K/vIgfKFxzW0LLQSzpVkduuVHPZGaGaKqLcp2GUTGNvZ8MLNexzyHgpHKLXTPIN1TM7rnVjtoZk5mc2goGpv173/Dk60uwFdEOB3TC7AQVQRzgrEy@tmcS3aFDwbSIjnliRGapUuzWr1612hxX2dF0R3jqEzpvj1z00UHVKPNBK3@3s00f4YWpXBxTvz18KR6wHYxJqRyG1DRMJh1CyaQJ/aJgTznjcVvvih0Ltw92w/KYfNoxVH8YqPA7fU5eUHBWQtPorn2wdVtZLW9tH@@V7DQB9GpfaKC/JL0dzLCTaL1o@qpaJGgbQfE3B3Orc2HXl1dNnBe9pW6Yd8tjK2Bx2KTgtPIlmSXVPDrgq8w2vhG@0Vn3jDah07KLWwCPLsYImg4z2V1iQmMpNvs81169u7Y2ZmVqr2rnGX0usKgvyQreuTZZwGarQcqhggVTz32Fhv6GoZ32jGhrtqmkhAKEQK6f5qIPbmfTthRFFhGMHUNUUj9oLJiDMcbzshFS54b7FZU0isIK/qt0@mUO2zbbdHXJFeD0TW1qSHqXYm5nUVtV6XfRGQzmF0lqBpo4yiS1IVDtTxv2t5aqe0HIgDaDwprIyEAUcUs06F8YqY2khjHdc74yvqDc4UoUIrUcSRs92KOaP8Fvq8hph7dSRUWFNL7WKZPglDjb7Qv9YZMVd3FDkL46i/kqvcYHGqUazDzm1hqEqb@nRRKEGN06hJaLZgoSP6cJlnjdPGvIzC8ctZyRptGMhuUCGVI/E0IuxJxjpa45VcQ1h5sVjHQkMkYg8JVsNn2o17gm2hczBdG/VvDJ5L4sBXZLfchOq35TjDYqiqnejuvS4ui9AALdvHWtgtmJAMCtoiOMYkCRUlhyHfxCEUl@qOaTjmdPMAJ88iUGpM4LLzJ8b3xix3PPnsbmpGCU9nY/H1WYUxfNaca0wEOnlZSOWT8QKsvA0FgaUBT@C6XAEeUYwnYjlJIK8QIDRmCaYxSAkT415XrV@xPMaYoX33A@Tmw2tPZFP5s6fP59HHU8tMVA4H970RCGZh8KMeiLpz2G0nKGln/t7BMgLee0c0VBMJwuAgqtO@jO8WgMZqlK9zunz0MPpB2NepJ2GPHyoOMYiNLtn89hfXKmslO4Y8Nsh231MxODCjkH/qjRe0glc5sAjLAknhxxVOMVhhsWhVUNnVP5TUTOOIAgkAzQIEo@VMq7uO@tqX37YITAblXKfya50HsQQoChAMeahMDrIxzGwLiro11LCZT1f4nyAUSU75DWcvRsj2y9rYrt8Gj584QZ8dXovr9AZwuMbgwKV7a0V/PO2vI8as1s7GzCFE9iPlOH9q2xqGaPqojBhpMhM0ISP6LWjJngzHEKaKn/9mCjrF9gkcgEfxM4FqXcIIbyHCO6Q1oXVq1i2wMZDKdeR2aNxJBNEBTCPvv4T6C272sLhGLJZ57ywVExkBGIaKgedAoqCooE4Qjhmh/ulnYP13f3XNHJ7ldL23mYJMYOAWcfA2@Q@noJPdcwWH6pqPCN4/AKF5j5VayhlotRotasXbB5Cq1cMHgBWKKdCqcEWYX950Y/Ac3JYAaIoChqYikrDdEJwo@6qAhOdcUMQ8ixyq8VRKNoUdhLSgTd6Eko6uoyUjsZSuAttWjhUIKgzPclIfCsgZRqO2eVTDPmoC1ovXXbVUMiTn8SRYLNq@KvktE26qOLRB5Rmq0mVCMqiDRTG9g7tvUc/2DZFnb0CBzBGKT50s4rv9dhcP7MI3COP3VfxuBqDxFh0t8LEAxFbJGqmGfOzjpafZRxXGdd2xbVdQW1McI2rIENmnZ9d@RixsOGx5PBcMW8sOTNmT5Y8V5YwcxgMzr00@g7fhTDVoQnDaUJ9oa499NG6b@SUfSN3sbcTw5m7@5kyMbB@jkwcON75KQTmRgOGLTZyt0GWKyR99bvsW4DcI5q3yv8BGzpJEYPgaaVUgJ2WcJJ8og3V2JWBmIAakrXMmajunA4VhS8mEGLUPQbQw5uRFaZ0qtwBauEZp2mOKNj8nfwteIlIVsUp3G3ITU6Q3mHWbQQNuhAIU9ng0LNKYDM@rogiYyB6HKSGzys08KyUwbzq1BSa3vO9BvE0QG6xD9Q8qxfejfnRbojOSZ7MYgsYJHXid45JAYJ@BrkHUmXlS6H91vohjeGwcFzrGAcIvPNsi4/2jEKuUNDMf3ePd4zZWc86eLu8fmhM57OeyfHWxuahMbsQ@ap7Mu8@gdcjbhwxobis2MVFDtZS3Wy1YBPzH45qi21jsXjAf4ZLirlKsATrCnIsjgZXhRxBT9wUtTY3yKUjE0AU6Q5YhMeQhzcAXvSr3WqnZ7KNJblY4pdddikIBZGHNbsu@yhBtTGk@O3qNUD2uyZfAENKw66TkiTioHIw0/02aSOlkGG4MbvoBsDqCUP/CaI5YjkwaVjmRSATJXFYlmuDh1CQBNrReMnCw0jHMo4eX72IX3liVw63s9TKw@0cHWl071tltoKGVywVGmP@jUGHaYBHjhmSxxM81@rcVcAe6Q@7Ghw9ZFg4lXK4QMNnzKjkb52HXMawj1j9DBoIJSZCRX06j0sbOKIA0gSqLu8hGIj@DM6XIhIXS6M4gujpSbpKIxpBXASdUnSkoP9XdEOBx4otbXQnVJhxWs9F2H1xoRkwFAZzyjxSQOCSjzOEsI0MQuD@ZIiBjgNawRsVTgilfzBAHMreDck3rRAphePvuIyqgzc6JNcS28XtZ5u08F6IPUqVLkUmQlpKWXFtL4eDcZcFGPZOA4NGET2SnZJgR3u623IG5NDieCF1X@N9tT228aK6ESDfSDyy6WogfG7IA0ihcFv6QpFqNYLN1OaHmSSYRBU1CdYs7XtxVSHGQFIFbl1NK8E8sywjKYnum36U5Ago9SORl@bAkqCra07Prjeso7ySZVdlN2kGkVg1W5ZDR6O/r2Jb6H0V7vR9nZ3TOiutjH2dDfjgH/Xv0IEfTYwdpkI7RIXlcvRpI2U8beBjiEjRzyjlmz@E/vltnbUN@TtFb0eq/qm2ktGs@uC9Kt4OkbTr6x3LId6s3OS5eJyPgByC250lqVzPpchPPbIzwPT4yuXj4tpZLWeJotlc4pC3uCQPt/MSk7diCEvR@AeMh46gj2bXByzBPhOdxwbEFWzTgp5qsNoqEpTZt0k9j/1GLJkU51nRdxvsGVCPXYg6FkE7NRPle8sTTRltxRDz@JgMxyGLiOPe2/9LekOGYxuCw0FvROKsU29G7BLh7vu@jHq8myM4N@C7nDz882HJ868GWTNZyQfEHI9fUNIBywM6byAYbckM4sUWxfBwlKM0Zzy852Hkg99BO3oA0YuRqwmdIHEL85pY5GhCzGgzaXZoRDkWZaDdNJF0EaKwcze@ccjBWyY/hc@A/BOdQgZ65UNnkJEz3cYtsfMPYmXRqybJqbr3D5z4BHYenyw9OctB42Cp7cB@ONtOy2TLndx2pbS7pVxbjY@2zoCRA@G2asrs4z5HJ1WcUykfwVGGDqd6aePA9CIRIlv2HYmTZj/@HRZCD1gdAMZAm2anTgFLe7eoPyAQuGm9sa4XR35o2zWv9VVhmcMNSKko8xcwMP1aGhqQqVd7rjk0M1gwU2vBP@0qRs3KgEiewR5mdjvmNpQ@wJhX6avqTTWypjWMLKcDtSK/txiZwrsjyulVHZO1RyigPLk5rdkwN0o/VQgJFP6GIiZ20AXARZWji8GJMkAHsCIYImncikcdUnkwSY6Yzi7MErF3xQlH5fD8TqchbyYeqfZ7lxgwA3a3a@Ny6Zqkm0rFfTotAZ0M3ph@JQqW8/1pdXTO9bCehlLxyGS0snbnMXofYToeuovKMM2PTAavR51WdWhEb2FloY7K6vRcdnYRZS3rokPLEHcLxcH1OHZz4HRNgLA7UTzHZdmWeWO2jAJO41vL7QPgQa8PXYqI0GwSMFZYNLAazUcXydc@i34vy7Zb/pQm2k0YnkSNlmmGkRsTZQ8GUySLc8HEwHnwzwtUebZtx1iEHw2z1r@gwyCmxdpD66hqqoYFqvHlWC3@Av4uwt@4dOHYR7dV6OtM@K9CfSLbMs5gm597fg@XItQL2PpFbv1S5EudUfMtAUD7Q4eJiwKzI0Ea9tYu3tpQhaxcLHOwixw7JP5Ir45AEtDfFC5McoGVycibkWelZ/El9bHyjHPp1ijGv70rIumQUQ6H1F8IcRlJwxnidlHogCCHo4JVihBlIuaYp5ECQx@VUth9aLUGFB6ApInDZYbnktYNVvA@59suwYIEs3Pn8g0L0rW4awGnl5r3V57NiUd53h51fqnWCMfXI1zSsTavB0rwrwZxm0iXpil1oep5KaXIiMhzcrCxlDEwLvD2ncWnlDEUnw37tkOYBsVsaljMLUWQ9KGtgtnptz@hMJLiIn0nhcB3hgnUfimC/wqJrsuVq90NpwSRdSTkESIUmHQm0zkoXsrI3S1xiD2g8ZLE52WwHb23obpY7zuIb/EMRBH6/3M@JhafYpxJqg@fDOhHTv7In6e82ngQVasHQ/s6NkgNMbI92iMtC6kDf4vLefocalnko0S80wgCg/ewlSq@O1Zw7GLKE29lUAQBqTIs4h0e@/9Chpe3BTmQQfhFAwCnphAQnYVLZpfyaZiB9A2SScwHoc6f33cWUcqW5UfycfYIP5fX8d95TvJoHCqDVGUYl3opUKIyTNAQKPWUu5HuUvO@R39H2hvo78h4qP6OGQ/V39Hx/Kr@qhvjE@oIHDH0B2UcFNlfgEQN0CqR7yleGJiY9U6otdNg6b4DvQiWxsYbo6Vth5zImmNawHWGNILytXSo8wXXsQi/4xSWiUjSfBa23gVw/G6Et3jXRn4xRr8r8A@fX8BPtvhuW5zRlICYF@hGX31OBb6hAuHQ15ckSaLqH1bFNJXZCfTMT/rFRUOrakk1nDrKMphBhVXv4wZ/aji0ri@JoGyyCA5U3Agr0ke@A8sFi2BaeBEx6oI@@kvhqBuhpeQkYmkZClmMMpGd6JaIyKy47qj21lQh6gzLVeMnlByr7nsHSbnAeTLopvdZUp7SIIptNem2bZUVsY09cTuFZk8URK9r9y8uDXQUhTwgwnYCIUuAqzehoX30VbMo1eJiXvfV/XHGOHIMEPLJfh537us9Y9Ukz@h4lyyCEWrHhNCwmpiQvJMeuJoovQI@54s@vnHwqqc50xqwhusBmkAOmKH6fVpOIRXLQ0wPAYjBONtODzlri7uA3feKOfgM4xVEDkD6@CJmZUKBhjeWl7HWWmqd3txtWCphrc2GNpLMUIONrJl41Ze9p3F8ixi8u4HmYO3YmjXzVzB/qlZ@vQa5/4GlCZXKVZni0FkU7BmXYwNN89oWSiwUjhVXKkjggHLH7qJsOEyFYr7F@zjaXdVbkL1IVEa4ZFo05xLk2RtUNAotTS9u5E2cTAcQEbSAWCt@O8P3sgQQAyz9msRRVZgFYJdYOfQ7y82w6/jKLAuPjgTGvTYbGN@6W8W1Qu2MoXmD2K7ylbBhVS9EsAFJemVz6D6apMVLq85WGat72JQuh@AmYRtbk4a5JL0fWAqrl2b9mmAxzoeHfcrqTMGwdXpTdtNwP/SrXZMibRvJZ25E0Hg@afaFJk6QjxIEaskHTCuvOMqEaMDIfqIryMCykvd1eFUjaR4p62yaXfOZKyL4ijsjHFv97gdvTdIG0Ct1IQPHc0tY6Fou4dHE75SBcQ1hMmwnjXlICf2d1b@Qsaw9KbITQ183tQ8fEBNWf66GUaihdBWGGB3j4iRmSvMw@MIINFY1BniKoZWMpY2vGjQYSt@4@Z53yCjIu7@AbLo/j3E8DAHTRF2LrilECCyTjaeoklG0dBSPYu3YnSkdM4ONIgY4BIs/dv6KP9L8GcgAdZD2AIFB83e8YaxX8bKSmi6kT9jp1EtcyKIrQAcw8m61Y9p9tzX8VS@EyMQA7eIF7wxJQ/o8FZ9@dhzFMJbOMhgMwNjK7JK6G@omoKAOxDu/vYg50UNBanDi2rY4Z42WMINxQd4D8mM26Jkodoh52yIPD0epExDIQZcJeNODagI9svFKsdoAkE4yF@v00lROKthV670@EdFLG5UrUKe0b1LE7jaQEUinKUGCjX1B5LZjdrkyWG1Du2/I8xnWq@fqEwik52vTgkrF0Uf4kTZjt3Dd80ECeBC3hgpVDi9MrQyQX2g4gGvRWul4gyXCdxR4uPHrFtB/fLLKUrXwF3FbbAPnVfjVtfErHN75YpWIO1Aui24FYLNpt2QicMkTId/HpaAf0H@ScZEpQcLyghK6/fiSQFoVo9dyUoC1lkjRImYVUVPjOVpYwL4E0DPr/EkR31pYa4PuznAWb2GBmNVu/RK6BPNl4YLpdWmcGlbDUPFKMHqeeMxwDUBfxFqZge702zV0SdOk8VJmmvTugZfkABLzUMepZs/00iIKZyVhPb9HVU@6P27E1d7iqkguQeEHANU9Ep6gok0VjodEA4PfnmaTGp1mTHziVUgehwW/z0TilAi1BiM0kpU/l57rlciXXwpizN2DMW5oQU18JmERCi3sqTjd2t1rfjnCazdXRidErleFXXIjWgip0JBM8nLOC2tC@xkPlstq7@FLXrmaekAUW2zQw4ZT3gCrIHtSaVlpI2d5bQEJq/MNVEZkoWYUl@WXSybsavHIN1e@Q2TboKxuuiXGuqhvBZ5rcZXJdm3dVlNwV761ISDFiqDgqaLleP0uriRlHVOEhqC48SzjUOOTRQm2JMydpvSUOxT/uZ1y@MRaMTvLWbkbeX0Ui7w6vDqUknBdU9VNSPMG1ifzDT92eVhUARy@btyIYvB16pIxEPpdZGk1YA2viYD8bXCPz5AlnZgYfsno0FgoNXEtjBOtZrENSO5QyoB5XhsBKU8Sxp9Cof0WhkLDB2/NnQ1JVRtd8wL@7FvYoob7DPkl9fKdjqzxZeLe7tbOYXm/sl9@W94/KFNJUuRXBsV9J0M3Ze4tOvfuCLzPXJ9DnMhx14JzHE8cirOEEvhB3e71jHUQd00Qx6@rULLaNyNj39zz2@Pzjlyzu8jlD0UwbDS@J01j10IToT6qKkH/blkA5@fhmBvnxQ9nIDmkQq3XFnoy4LhQEaSZQMw5B@kn7qSajc@8LGEIywY8Uuxm7xY5QCFN@N@Y4aRpNWA3m2mhYyuh8crB85egHCIgAwD5qHU7TEdOgYfS9ypGMbUw3FiV2or0nGTv1ayxx9WuUbXGGvcLechqy@5cRIT3BK0FxLnBoQVrzjQX5RCTURBUgXoL6CkQR5p7xB3KoHyQyaWzmR/OpYH3iP1r8lbwFSb5X2nnPWqnHxo/KcxsX8YA8AVu89vQ@cImhVrQhUdr8hvUBSrKi4q@zpx8vDW5QF/4NVuQjzEgF62b/nGMxn9Ye@5Hm1l/bx8LP74ZTugC9lnlyOUbqmJ698MZ7Py2WI18mbnIQ1YUP5lOhJtOiIBqX2I8QfHGYRSR89ja5Qt7vGpS1z@u1O4W4YwCPJmkWj5FWxXBxq8078WjEZrIj1Oi92nQ@9TKf2Xq8OP7GmIL4HU3XO34C3qtGUf4Opr9Ik14FajnARV3XVv/ztd@Wa@uto8q7d0h8p7eRRruOdFcv4o0UZvPnw2fGjhburCOLy1/oWGuzFukU3ntMk4qo4uzQ96ZccmA@jtfCoaUVkHeeiJGFofX8oeYE6tVt0kUcNkln0K8kKPiEtfd6PgF1Na9EfQuS8mJmH6JL9oaS@DYYCAqOhvQ9iAenCMfSu8ydhxK/9TIuRhXmdhoIzYh6gX@74u1lVqCbODxk5HVr9HI6ierkZ@sRn6yGrnPauSXHO5g33aGEQPftLoV9m4B/OKii7ebPfRGz07klccWLZbBtzIewRn7Df@WJRXUdb3jhJ59je@zMgKC8FEdRXYi3a46nz5jQz/T0uc8fNsVZYGD//aK7xo4QsK3DZuEwaYKSfAtt9Kf5nTNm4oeRGERr4EjHNgcATRGFFoqHFo/@@aZUVw2FtE/vwwZAEcTpQHrp5KmOMnt13rIEaj0BKfj@7LltIYqPcPpDRMdiKvU5wLLbVVFLni2LCCDkQ6eRQUw7TmrOazQsKvsF5ytxaZ79lQ0xm70W7ZKfcKpeDcmk85EWS/i27NzToLVqZImBRTyiBaP5B3HKXBN87pCkyy8hgPCZymjY7XO0@Ie7EVMMBBx8RTf44mE8rBiIzQpFLtCoZLu2b9FFyFiCZ19a52n6SJcBIdBdtebWKCRWMDyCujAkK6FMOBFxcWoAfivaIRoqr54seazb69whXdNt943jfKgbjrKx71clWTgMYkhMY3ddWN/d6/sR40trnTMASOXF68UUkc0jLojz7QUTDgwr5cVTpSfwdxbk3MlCv5WQB27qwHxZzBXVkAoznFbGp8@Nz4bZ40UBRPgSYk14udi0mWPVR/Sdbvf6X36PPhM0zs4y52nYQm8MO7SeK36YmRYxE7sd1roS0cuB@Kp0L0/Po5XpHq8VwulUC0DYWNhC83ZwJ6P3wlsERVrAKYOdiadjl5ghU6/jZTARu5hUcQpgOGoX3qBE0gmKWJg80DDpkCSSadHkpPGnHLAb@qRU/yVPbKS5LhKFrxKeIUpPGkX40F4tQGnZRufrc@yMi84gPG0aMyrTzEXarTRB4@YRi02A207H0z2XMvm00XrcyPi/zWy4cQMGv64EeKU4g2Bwbo8al7kNe4Do/U9AqaIgwTjDTQCR7vAB8jbZASQyo9irIS30tt6IUXCW@ztx9HmjKnFQxdSJLwWr9H@qfD2emA26rbdbbBjSfxRadpd7XwNnTlYNiMVj9usRrCgWIrE4FS4zhj/iYfUIck0Q8B6PJc/c@esQmE804vdC@8fEb0FovPagCANIrMYPNb09FwwXT@SjGWteBBCa1QAGHAGTqqH54ItQnxJt6hxw9uKlG9EVCfktcTRCCTnXAOlJTQGdMoPyrvGgwVQBCEuDk8WDZR3oh80GQ6qLX6C17EG2qrtRgWaDAfV9scI1qkwrH7QZBB0hK4RofSPvWJoE7H7Jy8@ho/V0WlVmQOz3u/xSSOND2AP9WB76IyWgG5YF1bvheExWvQrjQH0YNFOzwvPRjLtOYhsc4r1oQKS1dabIKr1ECK10HgpK6Rig2JZ6eybx5gr5tEHz6GKUM7RQM8IQp8Ggy3pREMkkyEEGnmKSVZMHxouNegZS6RUYkSNyU/weYfc79nkJxZ3OIJXNBWN30W5WUs@Kgp9kslCPnr@XI5FumdXLCP0vyXReBHJ1/DjSHtJ9/znw9HvqVSMIZ4CGRblT5ASENeSFNbOIP1cxBkP4kB/h6N9kQUBzfnD7QDZKQQHNiFp3NcpHYcUqkZxJB6NQwpsozimHt8OkqfC@vL00ThYEAzDkXk0DlyBo2ManfwECO7432jYUvONB6q3iNRqquZfGgpn1fdVC/ZFiqoG6n0RBh/8IPAV1g7BmOtrvaWJQY8aDxQ6RscjZvFOWoajmCh3ls3tc1gyPrJfWLilVA5tpe28JeNnbq8BB0G62VL7O2TzB0T0wCWJQEj3HijEpOuXXRCRcDZlsELJgBBOineGV2wc7@xne/u7G/ul15Wd0msUoiaZRuH1DfqZc0m/O53HuGR821Khu6GiUdrfeIvdiHDUNS@PQw0ymjKdIhQBBEtNftLg7jjWWRdrKtJ9Ubpj3hrrGAaNFKiDOBEyre5mYHpi1AZF1KNTNyK2LkHqJ5jslZDXlqElBMPrRLSEYLTkiCZscfn3HfZ18L7zvseANeNMhAk919v7HhVQtIKGMXXzvvfW7NZsF1/KpfMJnkV8SkXZjYwMUflLxJfxMGgT@MtMxliRzk2EHlK1VUfXJf0mOTBpWxzsLe1cOpGmWxRmRrFnTRedFURuql1j67C8f1DZQ3/L5VV6Acf/lijvcOt1effoEHMOIKsgksv7@7v7FXpo3D/aO0TPD4GkqA4osHhgIsEHtLO7WdrWYPg7KhrJD/sUgzklTbJShuVUBvTvkJ7rU/ycViFnqqRugEUpLWX0rLZp96UTbrQjkAd8CjUIUIcZ6pLRaciwKBY3PkVEnuez4k6DonZ0@06PQOklMxYYibi/BMO03QssQDZlLvDt9Cqavu2i@IJ5qJBlO7FAWVR0wGIRoafT5MjMuE0Ohp16TKITDhlSn8wOQGLg5mf9XnNq/tldHL0D4Mk9WvhZBk6ODDm5eBZeUoygeF2MaM5o9WvXpYhUXAYo0gygSfA0DKgAX/MvGcmkFf8U0R39iiygquwH@JOh6UL7YYQf0gltjtg9Bb/XQP24QNQvoUmh1gh/7nlhcmnUu0LjjB/lz1CDWI0Z/ZWd5RvmmJod1I38pOnnpvG9YhUaXOrF2GCHbK@9dScUO0QDKpgRnHF/HqAXzw2iw1Qhr3G3twQD1esODdYEozCVPFzQ83P8dyBcdMCBWr@MwYKL67DRKOeyWwFU9kClY1LoQDEvuhxd9MyR@HlZPQAxxHMdIhcG8Ts6RD4M4kaHKIRB/OLnDGI1Y8mknLxlIz8zw69SvvkMKf6/VPGpKQn7XD5peYUBn15cBeAkJGXGIaCTRVTr089sQK63bPbelvlR/@J/R/2xSkWpKaqEG35Ps@/B/Df/KLrIN3SPGKV/zz3UCBQyJ0ygDlgVFe8LV8USl00SOoFBbH95D7ZoVM5ieNk/8lbE74xZNL/4Kx9M@LL5Aznvhho/4R1HBL6hsjnvdTqI4P@MIih@CYIKl5f7i7xGsCImZucXFRbZAw8BgxR0kHwQJKzKz/dWmdXx5UKrzOkg2cdU@Yu/FnWK8ysE4s8UBNFaMZihoP/Pt9HoiRUKhYG6DIm6EQL6/D7wC38b9GJh4Hsedipyfn@7/@Z3g@32SobC/@PQxUkF9PUlpz104P/LY3EUxuL4jlFMTY0dt2cMkUyOhfjFn3vt4OENbrP7Nsnf/NOHS2fHl/6HXmnvmF@WBzdzDRJZkATesfQWzKSiZwobzx8MgEoJaY12jKo9p205PIuF4o@/AzmVLTSH/Nl5mT0MzS6o7ADyO2awJJeEdtLEGD1nT/HEGnm/SVuTGS6ZuVzUubY4d0jndplZF4rCMDaKxxEqFRrTsxwQOBI@IWMUtciNC2bvLkJc8FKo8ONWu9XLThUDbbh2Jy08OVp2pty2ryw8qLoZisp55Y6Thr4Pa00IOLY7iq@lbrc6hKYK4xDWnmS5HQGr9Xq/3W/hG1pRyFVo4JbJoOkvCYKdftsVOPHEXelbLehBETk1j0UUcT7pFAZW@lHVB6oOq3a0ykyGdR3TZE5MSdS2etdyelRZcVQWQNM9YlChCuu5BitZeFQ0/kSI2KVIUfRn2@qYMQ0eo3FYKS2B9NuTRS61RCsjOCYajhRqgOz02z4Mn8SMk6OPIuek3ZZVN2PZVB5HzsR1Y3RN9PQonXeiBVJe2BKTiRAiEVFdu34s@dR0nEeJEO3B8mz7IaZT@SxW5GAWmZqRhx@zO0R/kxdGtUnmZ6ScSDgIm4KmWQCO0EMvxnU5C72DDNWuYvTv/uPP/1M0/imTkWnkG9XqVEFmIM@SHlb8PLT35LeGHuUToXMWwP2fPdyMumHWrXYVPY32NNSwuMZghglEzJ9goaHxod0CemNf6KE4ZYW4sDKZ0tqacbi5v3t8YJR2@BKBVkGgOC6CRSOa5GGnkr584ecFQcRKGIV5LSpGINmIUSjVKwRTPSYzqWZM4EaWEUbr9/45jRbd5dvoEYD3ZQAhZkfZOAvvCeErpqNVEyFXMM7D7/0zxmw77HUgHLHtRMXChJ@OCYtfXkXGRvrFEOH1/e2f/CuqTmhBY/RGC4MQa1WPY/op90xcyNKancqdj@2VrxoahLGIHxyi3/8LQuZysCVJCCMTOlVUSMK7/Wf/ziAc@PgAs6eVNHx4kg8i@gNGpF4PaOTG4pt6EN8fMr6GRa8AOqLa0N/F13BOprt2v9OIacmZB4bvb/9EtBjgrR6@mdxTR8LX3EjoZPxPfWaprJiOcfOr4R87w3@qIxXqiuMw8kEViufnf@1tU72b7AKH1/eEtjsDTQvt8M//b9jqI2sK2D3oyYnR6lMVulfGtPnf/FuFfxCZGDywYP7uP/7xn3t9HIzt2WBsf/7Y202D0V4MxrV9IkCSTvDIiCYHY6fir/zV@HbuoKh9jkPwl@PGfeAf7MG4LQ9LX236wQPbfhySP5BI1IYfPLjlx@H6Q4krdLMHuzVmuw/GbnOJfcxGD@BPjGkmbMb/oW/GwX0zP3bPj18W/4GQI8OHhnQj05LJCA4nS6wthgFskoZcnv4uB1ujUz@8avMYlyJwVIAOpSbf2kOowXN9538Kxga7Y77GS80JpXnZI62WnKgFRJNqyw2pqlj8werK49CBuBdSy/LXVRK5y2Q6Jrux6zsNlDro/a5NkkeXnv/QCVw4ZfxdmkvgtkFcMVB9gt2xnFGTz@kFxx1ZPoiObMekqIGefBogbtDf56q7UzlOIXljIoilZTNLNEHX6SgKjRVEhCSRzJ2HChUsp4ZuhP@mKBBLVzWWrnCwRB/JH4iX8yDx/v0/VxRJjZLtxx5AmXwY538V00AqRvRWTpYXgqcbj7ro@1KClD9VHgFjj@7/rlOLQHXjeUkNbBzmP/oX6qAzXdRlbUB/QBxhL24Y5AAHZuwJqNFP/kkIYvGERzLG1vwv5cS7TKHGVY4n2SPqGVPNX/yTKC7t8EHi7KWHhSyBcayMZWztGEcH5X1j9@hw7@gQL2R0A3clg48X9FjsZrpMAqz/kmBEll0CMT/P4qyWx8vLSlnJfJy6/6//GLvPaJPFaDaqDdO95f7UVy4ny90zRjQVjx4hMT4j5fnSAlrHdYveFovzYoRAgN7q9HC/uib8EGB8McGOe8TZxsufXcvpUreomPE8Yup/yG5plzHjLxPwqMMJKOYMnL9i9qeV8eOsDLqyGuLrXTHsNY/xQy@k6wYC/bFXkO9mcyny/wE)

Ruby 2.5.0 is separated from other Rubies with `(defined?pp)`, see [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/).
I also replaced `\'ppp\'.bytes.class==Array` with `(defined?__dir__)`, see [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/).

Until this moment we used golfed version of Ruby/Perl/Python code created by Sp3000 in [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102433).
The problem with the code for me is that it is very obscure and only 4 bytes shorter than straightforward version. I switched to pre-answer 17 code
because I think byte savings are not worth increased complexity in this case.

```
old(golfed):  print((1/2and 9or 13<<64>>64or 68)+(0and eval('(defined?pp)&&173||(defined?__dir__)&&-4||\'_\'[0]==95&&91||93'))^1<<64>>61)
new:          print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68))

If 0 is truthy then it is Ruby, do big eval
else if None is truthy then it is Perl 5 (#9)
else if 1/2 is truthy (==0.5) then it is Python 3 (#1)
else if 5<<64>>64 is truthy (==5) then it is Python 2 (#5)
else it is Python 1 (#68)
```

Ruby weirdness:

- requires space after `print` for some reason
- `and`/`or` chain works differently in Ruby than in other scripting languages, so parens are needed around `None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68`

Note that `&&`/`||` chain works as expected in Ruby.

**GolfScript**: `"$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"`. Pure: `"#{print 187;exit}"`, `()` for Prelude, `$' '$` for Pyth, `/` for Perl 5.

Answer (score 8):

## 202. x86 boot image (QEMU), 9700 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLeljF8kiWVKxqrqqKJGt1ocz48Wsj8cP9nh2MPasfc6Md7HzYGAHi32w4Vks4Hk1Bv4N3zwtBgucf3A2IjKrWLxI3f2dc3a9gCmRlZfIyMzIyMjIyEs1Faf361@H8cMOTX3U1U2Xuarjsrat3ah2iq2P2DNFc/LZXCiEUHW7O@irhuuUQ2EmM6YZLa0Nfuaa16qhfVJtCM8yZtlm11b6zO0pLlOdlmKpDjMHrjVwmdmZnyzH2FbfvNKSmLKvGV0Ac1XbslWX4lcYOzV0pd9sK1Mx@akMLRviHbap6p/7n13WMvt9xWg7AFlg7JVpOyrCt1THMTH5KmPDLbU1hbQIoIqtmXv1/edTUSXGnkMRFUtXh0xpOq6ttFzNNJAmGXa8f3p8OJVCltmbk@3t6dAse5k0DbY9aF1PR@XYqe0oujKNf4XVB665606H51m9qxoKy6ZKqex0ZIGt28pMklVmq0q7o@lqChqEJVlP1S3VZhjCOqbNdqFIejFTzDTq45SpFqYtjiOn0ZaYnsu5U/XJZoDwpt1TDShhZjpS9iOnIrJ@RFujDBR7xKJOz7SBj2w2cNQ2uzXtNjCXoY9iCUjPhp9YU3HUwgoiyPkIrg3z1gAmck1o2ubIVZlhGklKjIArTN5rTDNWNo@h9YPd6fACy@5Nh60Co7WuO7NtmS2yI9MaTYeW2Cttbx475zK8I2yYbWiNqTiZHSoQRNlMEj6XnewFLWhd6MzsyoGCtVXmGJplqS6PBF5RbYqG1EzXjGvewQ9tsz1oYedzeyrkjR0W@cEJtSBVjVlCTKTQwcLEQRwMSnBs9tVgeR1mqNBAjqW2tI7W4oylDl3VcKDIToppUIlbTddZW9UhwRh7K8EcE5t3HNTUlV6qlQohY2IurH@tM421LIvxKKgFFGk7U2QqUo99gni957Ch1WeO1odot2V2OqrKPqlWD5KH2maIwadlTVXL9y2pAGOoHmlUCwQCksZESgOdPArd2gqQ1nYEDVytD4TV3IjDVMXRUKBCEkc12kRVyxe1JlMmWJ7daNDhoeoDm3A7qk1djvBC97RVQKn4zRy9tTXXpV7D6uxQVWx2YqtqbFLsTmQJmZmYg4sVSVGjrq1Ftg62I9C4PEVKsaAx7dzJ6xchhaWqbKlRgW9Vkiqhrf1Ndrd0gW4uZYEBLDuqxFj1B@akLy5U@A7lZrpr34cAawioorO0ablpJWlBAZMuFDCtoBNdyZtsytIDGbO1qbYIsByHakNrgPBhbxJUs9bAtnEkGRNVuYZK66bRBXpCZe2BgfQwWCEDTdAyYSBIMPUGqAaSl9oI5AJS@KSnQaM52CSBjsXHQyIojIjAxoKiXr6OqQ8IDlI6LvIyUAWSIsbdDnvDOoqmYxKIR1S81LbqDHQX0wyMNrY8jHdqO8W8YlCHtYGPbyA7BZBSALB@P9AvqVAADA1hUlUx6sd/@mftbhfw1FstkG2CXd@wttmikVuhwsJwyJBhQaDqVCyAS2DuPDlkcKPoWpsEhGKMRBZUCMr11hzobWZChvatBr20p9xAz4bO1XJVzuR8sE@wvnLNpYnGORcq3lea0LCUAeVN1U6yZxvQSi01FCaeSfYHbqfIktYWizjp76NPy9GnixcqFC6Wii0vpdPdCjBcapmCwBd5jHPe1CckpeMqjqm1Q9bI7ZlGliVbTGpVTUs1opEJHJFExG5GYimUctFYRau2Uh3NaEcja8CLNcg4Equ0qq1zrXxZmUoezBLQ3CIa7K5qtBWTQiByqFPcpPsgzVMwOLxJClcgznQaSHKMTgWCkTDTYTc8IEzKDvKliQwCcijl6KpqRTMpOYZiAuHm1hsj5tV0CoeocFm7jEfCkXiw6oQBajpRUeysJ5qJYku3ejhoAVEMx4KRwEbebcFIjZLR0VzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEVnFI9/mIuiTvcpg@iYJSYBh3ocmerLYDHRmEAPRl15mRxrp5CxlSmXCYAdFhYKZKF5oGEvOK1HlFeE4UMlklrmgAtqbKismmBp0AuxvIdMHzgboBeC7LYQAb7yQB2dNXRoClxYfVcYdhWgf6Uh/EA2hDLRVlDggflQ8omMmA@p8DOjZq25lkNp@f7GMzXcy10/XkexDSn9KP9iSsfLAzoaBhHfWW6YrRHShdlWtiTGm1VMsVggpq4rggiqbHGwpMisEz5fRCS8@m86ZBxFMtxnmgkOetJ4ZCBaWLUPSToM6oTBFTFdAcbRBL@mg6dwC4mcpc@oAgEwX4ID1QBE8DACZTh2pr4IJUAwa@7WmtHvAsls7gcpEPQtPZQ1Awd5DsyY6fNRZGrj3JhlJpPwiL8SCKJLboLB4YXBFVbSKAGj8Y8DhmxenPQWz6RYSBIBCaSisp4L0v4OybhjkHKRDSR4sgkzG8HUATO0aFEgYuT@2izuprmX4TQZvhRKCN/NdzXcspwzihub1BMwWckj6xR7vugYHMknbtkeaa3N3UzSaIZQf6Z9rLId0aNLXhVIUozG/DKyd0AwpYx2FVGLk/DoDropGOAwKTwjcQOBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2HRPE2CJXjkdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKp8uG2UcpxM5IMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6X/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyPlSA0k@@LiU3CtoespuuLgekquJLkQLoUuSpEgF8aeUwoMu4zcn3uYh7FLbLYhjkqfNCuqnJfLucuEci6LZxafMRB1INkAOokPwBOJVavojMWk2i1UNNXsTNZ@A6XzccvWLEGEF8qNwv2CCjkig9a3cBppqxUcZB@nSb9qwygISmurF7UjF@eZi8uLu4t2/OI@ksDUsYpSbUKlIL9oP9W1zQEMl7HzlXJSvozFznMwSDarkUxkORotJnXISInFvivG4gqndjSigtSOXlxEgKiCPuetnk34holsLOaTCsqBAzPohNFI6q4I@Tdjl7F4BNLGIgmYYlQjEaBMC4ngUKWRMycIdHD0khNmIx4PERua9jV@Z8Q@hKVggsWTbwP/bhxPTnv71yBdWcvRURVJ2lwbAW96mQe26eFrXGW2SxqrAcMt1ABG27Y/M8LZuDEg/ZmUWzOYEU0HEYLCcOxBuapNwCDijjaECQL0@5GnCOH4jbrQBkw4TV1NnZFqIjHoODjtVVNztaFDPqykWs6YB0DvAaelKy3o2JPoLiR2AQiBz9Pp@TGxygziaVWJZjVfqiMMLC3FQPq1NdLaB5rTQ/KCZoVTCbsDVEWVHXQDlai2y1ow5neB0upQc7kOD3x0jEl2FCcaQ62xzrUuVPZQY8BCeTYAGs7NFsx3VNAcMJZPHtmWcaPZpoFETm0BamD4CrbBFPJ55AU2qtd3s5sP03cecqDYTLAcoG0Q6zRxW06LpQ1TN7smWwYAZM1UijP2roGmEtD5XJheMkf7RASqd01jNMWDKg73DuqIciHna98KQqYJPnUFsobNr/QY4IE6H@@@34IRQs5nMlB@z5ehj1/JAJbpOmJgi40BhMlWR77BlnyvWr3RhEEJ@YPPIoGfTJV3TD6vV2BAhVKJHv6JkgY7OQ@Bfu5FtT3XvLpvkYaEpozgLGOi9qAMQj8V1eHdBmoYngrGUI8UE0hnGnzcvtsgO096AzWktnomky5Aw8jWWLqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UmZcxPJkzIIdccgFbXVnWtr7m7ZO7SDVRdxsOyF4tWuzGCQ011Q2K@MRavaJIay1qjy@G3hjggOSGVnmz/YHOrcVg/2alK6YFjp3WtCRzcVht9UDx11ZHY9CfMjlRAJtJ/utaPTNOt8ua61tkXP2FM4yXf22zs7a4f1Y/e8UIQGkfrD3QFi1JemgLA5McU7fWqgB2wY5t9XyN3REMs5ZD06oTNH6enInYFYwfC4h8IL2B4H634qVao22qxpMm9fqAAXEVAtOzTGNaNxxGSLP1@oIAsEkq09qfsphdYwkDfzj9hAR@jmxf/cCKB@U7O3CNyxxg4VqBmd7JM4Tdup4Ojth@cpeDrJLK6Pg7OUTBfJ5i00AuyzETNBfbxrRA@vr4wF99M1FxgH1@e48N1ifnopmLmgfrICoQM1zHm4pqKmAPoY1olTMG1j3FckeIeWvgQec2NfjCRj7tEuHFxZIyKlkpEkAeY5dzR5wsXTgNtpGMeycoTsRjFlztYsg2TkzUEQX75jAshEARanGO1U@7QHaPIBVEkQefgyyB@PGcEWW8oDeiV49J6IYEoltRBgMmFceK8n9icSmpq42AfnLdrVm@ACBgEurQXEozyE/Em9NZbgp0iy1vQNq1RoC/fZTnx@5oQJ4HelePkJjmE2pE9EcmpbXlrLhNxvFvydZbGFTfWNcQyC7YLF4QnMPTumaAw7WkOrX4GJWPIV@wvQpI3O5lQw6VxTHZsJWTJm/nmTSmIiGQ2iNVrEyfFY1cjk5LziMVH0b/WZ1N2QLeknwnQmULNxvCxot/s0M8cgLKwnMGwiEtBSJUXaP1H454Jmr56S2BkAyBkQC3NUNJH9EBrwLzyTNo1JgrTVDsDUILTMElD9xfAkqUiQXaaTe0hUKALFt17zq3k0QAmItnUSkr2Zj1oR4SZDzdKnOweECD0396MMYxNNIU7sF1IJZ7/6WdtaJLZBuspI5oK@I4GUJK4pfNg@4mk6KGf@W1NMFcDXVOIMOT6EsqWgusPiu475qNGnYYlkz3F7qPGLZob2BV/oL89wnm85LaqD9qq95yfCZF40uTGUxtan2oET5wy0gT5geRTBkOeniZduqm0CQufGmkqJbKx9Xm7qEM@SQjo3iCdvqKcnl2PjRfS3N7AHfBfXDv7UrtqFn7nU6U8yWSZvNKU1bTpKE1NfYQPbOV60DaT1nWXKo1FK8yBHde/iWaoZEdXrrmzgc75BOBVtLVuV7W950Ngtz3Q9mmakr6lxyOs4ulajLRn5TGcts5/HwLxdq/4jofppOn08y0MSSzSgl6DpMUF8mSATNoUYXWlOcLpWu/bOQszJCUWBE@1FY9ncjjq@qsh46V4y3o4PQ7VlL5Ump@aL81zksybxKT5knySm6qozmKR/gu9HsYyra/oyWw74HxQrHtm0LFrDijN3ZMtXXGAmVzRHOoNNB/9PMbgODy1kK3GrkfYe1wcb1HsofUV0UtFT26ZuuZgd9YfEqPTJulxnrg5gn7GSdE3S9g26cVOL@m75ksCs@Xi4sYDjPYVko2vK@DKTYBzUuZDRGuZt/h9UNvomTcq/50/2n2aW6qvkFFJnVhCa80VoO3WlzgVF8jpZz4dr@eWy23pc8OFGX9ybvC1vOxouunAJB1/HyMFqNuOw3/nc3GQappiJMnaHHTPTyYKZbGUsK490JaK3jX1QrGbVuDnwQYf2B2U/OL5tRLPl1iy/GWJ5SlGpiGL54Oi/jptX3@JE8gkbePSVcD5yDg7T2yJJY@HKwgTClyPnl@57UyRUqbS3GLyUAPYrd6tMvKeP2E0eYi63mhijUjRBr0PE5SK4HBtrnz/lNxWHs@t/XUiaQbt6pcqEWjca12FwYt@Z5qUZTPyN6aQM5mvF1AdfaAO1Lny6aB5peKOxEemH19fqIyoxpKwLaaBeGhZ9KE@iWnkV5Uax230PSpgFF2DTv5F7WauvLNAF7dw5n0IjkN0zCbsGgNronEnpm/G0eOU61lezzbbE4XEmG@VSMUv61AT6rqj0vch1X6rb8Jk2eyD2mB8RfsLpGQG4b8TiClkrGhMWEvmZu@vb4MuC6oHtKh27STRUP51Qif70AyfgEslmLEZqjvC34coPU@INk1T/5aWAVna1mjnsZ7EvaZfaqEZNUdsdWBjW4aDdpFm5yErBh9nxOQSqIcTafeRqXPQNvXIbHDGzv7IaBWwun9pfgkjNZmJHLvluR9iSLKGyKliavVRduRaqNlUdYU/hoWVx/CVUrlH8flah1BvaZUGV3b4Ws54MSw8JXqsERBLa8PcpKf2VfI@otQr7auB4z0eBBqa@J0TnUrTysQD6SwN@rqBvxPrRgFtyDUNmE25it1VcTqi44KmCH1IvnoLHnOJu9tXuio/mPCY6BhbJXAPHJ/EjZ3z7RNlvi2lBcn4qv3jrAAd51odOd5zLsJXoxa056D/ZTPbVB9voTn0i506lZ67zvMFdc/omT2jp/Zs6hy@76HuARzp8iMlj1UCyt9TnGvc9EfyaDyb6zlB6uqmrn8NdVEeculomvMttVu4Yb8NSb8J70hpQoR4fNGEB0M2EYnG7of6Tk8dwMjkmK5pqUnyPQSqo7GH/843Pu8eRBx2pql2m@9YQMuf4mpNXWW3GhThygkuk883JDV1U8F9pY8o70AZ7/k1pqmWaX/R7tFVTNey6NGw9IFDP2TiTXbm2y7LbJtK@jXMoLl8swhnWbVrNls97UtFaqqKa2jXac@Gw72PzkuFMKaaayy5icEpXQNa2aMUMkE1GH@Mj92Hxr/Ams7c2m8MbHv0ZcEwuQXAN7XyJQN0PJS/WK2dE01DPu6G8nb9PLJuIRZ3H@QmUqBRWU6qGdBK5ActQBMbv4T0olXGB5SeqXpTYQILa99iuhS7A8iIpwV2OED4POPFQ4JwR8g3mBVGdwZdJ/Zlxu21QafCn7kI6108Y8WXlhzdvA0YmqHrK4Z4zB2V/WXIx9ZE8o8uiqTSYvEzqQ4etG7pmuXwX5bsZOdimV3Nn4UazZ/piuZpqx2@TIGuL2l2fdPG3e@gQiRbtuq00OKN0pdLRS5yDLMLUjipszGwBzu3CrMbCObpJpMjXPLtvtpVcDfcnoYb43RndtADzNN7Cb4G8euB4mivB6arzsU5vafga1C@Urpaa2eiFTyEHnXF1in@mOgEGDTbELc9zaFNyJ5jfsfhbEbL87OR00Z1/zDc44aQgF4k9oKy5C7z9oz6DjTrY7wyN69JrVOszD8o6DSXDKbiObee8/dfPGZFuB30rYEjHvNz7@ORgqDluH9N4c6tBlIw@RGELuspujvfuhwwnoI@JUbCsfMhLfu9pptd9r6YYaB@gYBDpfsBxlqHcflQcaEHGHOYlfL/ynVLtE0kuVLjfARGUHMsqRma@7gdxnUVmAd5T6wQV7XwyEx6D39Tz74VQ/JkPlX2HpX4MKSPWjrMbL4EdfjuCxDqxpeHli8su8BQaRoDN4nHDB8bIgqPDhFlNiwWAjzAoq@3Xp3y81PhMBqigqddnITYpAlhmi2O2jkp7zxrmDa00tkX7ywEC@OJnAEOz65ppxjBRaNKPB6LhXgiXOLoGgDmQdGJQjxtxA8rOgyo4BKs1mHn52zpbljOlOV7VmVSWWKXlxwrfujsy9bQouOARzz5@ZJyWV2KJJORpciFUWaZiA@u6tDR54IrE7AdjR68vGMSMEPh25bR7dW4wk9TOT06qQhKbRuU41ODbFaoaPMzQfzA2Qluqvibv2yLA5wwg3ZAq4TBFgiC55fNvtozb5/yfEXudctS8AAo4gC5rPPjSMmNOgOBAVo0P7dp3rLT7ZOiOA0mDkuD55BrWX4peOOiHQf3cru88Xhp/H25ImM/lVcpYM9B34B5S9vtOSl2rNE27YE93m8JLgQzXBsnb@0E22VtFZeuafc92St007ymYzRYkr/5S34Gjvbgi73RXvZ09jWQI261l@ngWatlDqDUHpJPqm0KkCgSGaT0AC2BDDsuhcdwZzodzgOOTHpH0ygbfj5to37MklssgufA8cRLRetEl@pHz9@cZy6rP7B@Wv1PP0vH7gThpO@SpYIjJZgHUrlHxgpG5yF6HBth0tJQ4hn6BxQ0cUDhlrcHkEjhTIZnFDweM01L9Bo6XkynaX1uFNdcRNFN7eydUevTyWRiWPWWzqjRxmADRy888ms40MHAGyPUvNdVl6IDbrBKHrssDxniOT8FXPwsM23Zx/NWmGRpyD6zHjJZsoXbyMHHCanjEb9@dd3b3ZQL7kFLb6rNAW2zuMmmsrkqVWepUV2rkctW2yYetT3//mKYzSQvhqtbl2nHI@rFxfC7TPYtUN2EufTSkzT2vK39zbulVC3z@bOjjJgk3UcqfM8ciImlu8Pdw63jk/rJ6TG0wr0nfrZNu6@MZQ1yEW0M75k6HWIGutia6nyD/PF9AB6NsiWFreH1HLFYKLjnmUAFraWktMSdAdE0kfoLyeeld9RA/CyAkGkdjXkctQtDEbYhMBtSDSs/sPAoNhNpxXFS4jINZTx2IJ8wuDNxjiwlUkmsCsRKArG@klTs4co@5WFfQ7EvYnmcbE/ngiDF/PzO/XhexbkkuP@t1NuCgfI3rzfH8ni9CeaRegOoH@ql2a7v7p0ebU0mAx6jJ0ndaikvNvtz4Yw9jdu6vPOzdC5KJERjX1ViEiXgXjGY0d0rTdW9VaFaQji2@jwxcSiVXwqNGRMoU8ULbC4rnBbRKJUAdZAKVmvqLEJHGwaK6I3RAXR3vIq@ENiWfNRewVOSwBymy0RS@PGqgVgFubyud0hCXMjriBNUfxJej8Oq4RgN8whK9cBQ5Y86DoP/wKjkubKXbMjEcCZfsiTLwldXYQ7d82FjFT5GsSVOCGmJl13yy4sXWUCZ2lcKzblpF5w4bgGjtK5YeGpeQO/DPLfMPg5MOtvlCRNfv7jFGZ3C72yhpm0pWBs6M2a4eALeG7cI3@72cRW1M66akXwP8tzAwIEKgAI3qGwNYbIGzNYhWc/vYuAkN8Wxf2@oJCOsI475@lqCw240h4y02Agd1HF0kJRYG1FxvL6ITvWxuu6ATtKG4Ztf9kPKSYr2bvMN3EmDSWHgyZSvMiaYFEJYpzp7DByG0tsWDKsfeOIlgiPMTgBnZG0xmQTKdTXDu26njLZkMrKVmWsPcMdDLTKTxCtCmVzJntvXA4BzLsS4UNM//tM/45dgXLjg/rlwDzPr4PtD4euA@594MbIMvn/m@7Lg@yPu@z6NTTZ78l9kL4y9D250B758Js3UCWWCd@cQ1cVvbWzpN7uHzCGDN7ZlXxkGmgklDPKcZgC9tD4wxQ21MYLzHMZNOMYTPX8DLAJ8BfyB6g1qNJSfal9G8fx3OZ3GguOsPEW7o9Uht3bTcfCPA7wGBZSwdCFfWJHTUMjkjYeQzmR2cTsuRxiLlUEmhm40q/qh2cJjF0xyWoquVgsVzhvpJeX7nPTBL@gSwIb4ROGcQRo8qeGngLiaSBZdUuJyDJPiQBaRIyjT2iZnNdAGo@QAkBgGG96hNlA3TUEq4GNDHbqkMY28CVATr7tCK53KL8PxECUBEceNk83p7jjeYIsnFAIdNBVsBukMwY4RrCzNY9bz79mFe2FciktbGDDeL@ewrgHufzznJhfOWXhKdfYKkej0BSBYG/bs2DBxI/Y2lJZFs@lsLi0XYgEOlQQqKC929c@AEjo3CIuWql2ZllPf2Np9cXB4PHMVBkFGpsEiLFJbi18kU4nzS98R8cs9SdT17fTxq/Vtj5TBUo33KiDEeMPCdDHn5TZd0gdyP@M7m2fzpoiZjOTM1yKm1cHkNu3nmcU@jk0HADf4xsqZXKOxu/vzy7XahRGeyf7zvOuBwqllZC5wXTh0OVBkuphYxF1vv/YJXjvopLyTPFlpfPmVf/6I@8fBD19m4V9iOL7RwtsZHqKzpv5R01DqgT3jUPdUmmdF1znwgnnlBVnjFVXGoo4zbIVm9psES8NEXWbvWxSHqXwiHXAbkndbnsMhHRLO3MpE18r4NPPhTjyM2PXHd0yIyxV6UDpda4ZuxTlg7yiafwY45Vi65kZjIUNATB9Km4V0Hr2qwQdTqudD5p@uclBnHKbIWhmlm5BuL0P8pgvmXUgRpzstDgdAt0PTYmMr2qbquY5Ap2KbA8iihROyF4M@wHXocaTiaKGClpWExEDPiFeUc7zFQVAi1W/no8NYqqcO21oXRpxoLAGi6TtZHt@GoeB1DqBXNefVAM1SVk@BOmDT5NbwMolhbK1E3nEFuU2T3c4PNi5DgAyTNmNlbrmInBrexUXY8GUWSfiUacYSkRTjMylxJxGtmZMhKsU2erjDkEwfnY5GKlvwjDkfzDua3U9hrWCY4Sz0HPcXB7nmmy4mCVBGOVdSmtFWh1E8A16@RDpBeOT27CYSk2ZYnG5HEXdhtKevSfFkoeIKoTS@YmRK3pVKvpybFA2lUqrnhPCcHkxKIMdj194DJ6gI0U5fsVh0QPfMOCzFyBu9iBoJx7VjLFnD4fqWGSweJ5sGPCgC5iwI2iGXRgf6o3gtWzRdhUbCUMdo4@OTZrFzOZW6BDdlEmNLaM/cAG0KLYGxEMxRIUmZ0IJ@AX9lLBG/RDMlLtNcomxDdNUDQM2NJjnV7ZF8AVpQrVntyfhcfUDAcKqWSmXRGpPSvsSAL9bmCERAO0eKe3MEoK84VwVUQxkNUBu22tZAXj57qRqGCgQCnunjnaHKAJjMjiW862wT4@vmKIcwL@KOOKgFBZ28hm4rcqeboK4tpStkGqvcg1rz4QL1mo7QbEbp/zadSlfuokt6dZQGXTNWiy71qnI8txyPLxnL0SUDta0nT9Cidr8EylwjBRPUIQAll/RYBfgZlL/qklFZUtaiS@1qdplSgBemyHeQ4AcnnbpbUu7TS09AWUpAiM2FTnTJoRtiMqmUfA/lwx6ylE4Az9zhVSd0SS1mv6TF41iG1FIDC/BD@uI4TsPmxXGajHcVMRdId/uiu02pYn5LzFyuywkogsv@gJXHAUtsumt4wONL6HLz4h5Q/3jGL3FrMqMdFaoTnHxJkzFfL1iEnEaZK4RMlF/RAwQcRoGI6E0osRgIk1//OiwXGJOeFnJRM/40n6nEI3kZpukwvw4/Az08vSzZ0t3FZvKGqcnIeUfJpz5eHl4fHr6NXURZiUXCGweSvCJ9z0pZ9nWfVZZ94MN@k084vJwOhdPL8pPVdPrDhw8w44DPeS1VA/HBP7HzZOTyPLrKWG11dTlRKC4nnkUagYLFotls7Jil2YWmaZbTbsPX7NGN0tEw/zx9SnnB9B/@GQ8T@QuH50EQERr@RrgbJR9mF6uKshxfyT4zKqlsJvs3/27xPnF32Fj7m9/rp9VFfBzg4@f3r9D9Ws5/t7j43fr6ykoCSMndh@8P39Xr9ZXNRP7wPP90JZlZXPuP/8fiYjabXrx0HKcBdS7hJ8dkcOJvEb4yy@fZNfsEn@sOw39yf2oH3Aq6m51PeAMPTE2qJFcikXwucvx9hH19Uy4yufZ09T//8cHHsBuuZdNnNjzd8MdwoRjmTnCAL@f5bsK18BqCFe7Do3S1WgXn6n/@XyF97QXgwZjRGvzU8h6uwihcS1YpyedwrQAOOZuFfP@vn/0sFK4Nw5/CsiyHR/TXCGdk/BSfyE@gdLKcllaLkmk@88o7DHy8sLQsZy/G7RlobmxaP7gH@UC7MjM8CUpun6uY4AZyfC1cDX628PO3//vf/unf/jH9/Sl9/wNepVxYfPZhkzEVRmD8lMvPZtphb8p/lErCJyV6xxA9yaFXs3CxmmjwUvksHA44pujg/zJBEt//jXChsHcfaPJc6VxONMZFWC6uHDwbfvWHjQvt0TY8JqmfOZsO8xrD9zBPFrBvgQuFf6hWj1z8e9XEv8Nj/GPDn/JBdngKn0X4o3/4@F78XaQQEUwgs5/F30D6hsLn4fPLy9c9@rPxb8fAv@ZH/Nv7hH@vXfw7aeHf0Wv8O3mPf2ymNqHw2tpaOB4/ApVRMO3XfE7hm0o1hM9jXkT3W/2wlYPCwbMQCycv48n7@/PU98N4pSL@QZmq@D78cBcU6/I@mVz7vhaPn1PxzmuinGvJyxqUlReZfr5fA8TxtfO1tVSjVqslL7@vna9NJhLpnj2LY0d9Bglrl@fnofAdtkUVf5bxp@Xgb1aS0uRFWQ@jdglcjJz0EAGM3gWA/lD4w9qHaPxp/GlGz9xk5Gv5@pV5MP4/OBhChDbMXJl2ppfpyW0QmSyjnmZGmdEw0zcP5DY4VfjL9MGpZTrDTDdjZAxZHg0nUD383z8w3VcHJmAzIaU7zLiIONOBZ/fg4BXg60DeV/CnZTKZIRRymLmB/4yOApyuGaPn943YReicSR9U0ApSciSViaQKkYh2mS9YHy/u7rOFj1Ii0rg4j1xWwmnn4iLNtSaWXanQJXP3943G1v5mo5FGPlpbij@LJ5/Bp1qLr4nH03Ct8vSinMT24/yXaoTTa08varkkugtxaKQshK2l49/4GaOEZ23xIgQTwbMz/J7d3txyFznIdXF25sfiTxqDyEVB8AHQ9Nz0Ew4GGujv6L998F/W/6tTFj2/jDEWvbtfi9Inhn@x2N393b34rcWiUeGJrsEfBoAfk9zd19BJQHfgOo/GLmP39zwMfqOxNY6whnms1SjxGBA6bJjnehGpMAYzpqhYbLu4GGYysUoTQnyzu/KZ1m1iFdrRstTEtTaYJcjLMQLJr1QqK8K9WqxUisItFwqVyrIPlQGPcAKQ6iitCjJ6JWzFsAyc/aMZNLbQTZ6RaFvt4JXuTy0LZnxyKfP5sx/UaLQ1u9HA8NznzxfQkyK4oaVaykNIpvj5M3TCSAxmg/umWEotwdxOTmfH6HuKo7iuHYX5fuIigttinYtIDOOzmQwCY3qWX1srrNRqhRVwF4qxWEVa4rthot14SY7dL6UlXg2Yp0XCIkoursYo9D6C8Sy8xp7WgMMd/LC7@zBRm63kY9HmSI35AXKpxEPYSiFajJfEX3UxxtbStWUm/s7Pc/GV5dXlZ5eX4/ELxUTlTqnK99U7pYzGg/tKS9yjiRsklSdPciWgSzFTuQg1Gpv1k3oDX0iAC9MggxkGksAJ4aKjZUfOydKTL12eY00uLyKRcuUZb9hinoUjFQGXjIDoYsUSVTgM00mtgzujh4SVf8vycja3mM4PvytsZUD9/ryMn/Pz82K2GF8G0bZcKl1eXlLo50VKc94fdi7ppqZq8lwu5C@TqMBcDTvLYYvJq7nwcsiiLUarGdbGVVobLWeLEAjtypq4oO6ouu5dXXpr2nr7VmurgP1wr76xdZLIrgHK7HZ9I5E9Pl0Py@jNj/0UnUP/0VZ98@AUEhzubdWPt57vvtk6PYRwB0ZJIBZ8@oeKOlAb6u1gcIv@hkqfDc1Rrq4Uy2pY8Bl2fvzlH/z4y//uxz//ox///A9@/PM//dUv/vQP4PuX8P0j/vyjf1vK4@@vfvHP/ucf//WfQ@B/gO@/h@@/@9Uv/sXP@Jf8fw3f/zMQ9tfiG4DjXyAlYPvDX/3ij//iV7/4J/8Svv9KfP/l9PfHP/nf@P9/FH/o/PMf/@Sv8Ud4/uCPfvz9P/7x93/vx9//@Y@//w8B@d//1S/x/4//6u///S/x/3/5N3//V//D3//h/0SOP@OO//tf/Vv@@3e/9wd/9/v//O9@7xcP/P7Bo7@/@IrwX/wOQr6@nF@D52vq9a0hv/hJ5flNqDHOhRjsT//xj//iHwHn/gn3/ffgg38/6ue@x4@J0@QuGR8H/pyxz2nQnjLPPvuggPJ/xFAIZp8nsVFoxgv91S/@@V9g8ATsPwpiyMizsEsI7Of2c4D9137BgrA///GXP/vxL/7hj7/8sx9/@Yco0JIrpUQ9kZS/YB0CwPxXwCFg4WvgAFBew4XyRbYYyoJjcQ2tGSE5/uEDkHQRXKCFL4fyOfCF5Bq5ZXRDQpjULPN5dRyNCPAdhlZK4EP7QhxGkDiPikPUepxVq9V4aFiFOAIFL6YZsloRZ044cagCXkzE0yQaRVBK2XCdsEDKavyINZarQ54wjgE1wsCwQBh0JMlZKV6sbkKG1eEmQ1yIPB76AM8P1VqxOqwhuh@oCIAjvg5ZAlQVSzes/QD@KuEE@NBw8wcoSrEaj9eKEFKlqlJuiQblKeepclT3OKN6YzjMYuHx9Blj30lyUeITOCAlE9D4Gx9DPyU7xlOIv4gvi@rQv@ek7zKmh3YaEn14GI9/isGUXgAA3mQSN1XBN5nE0jyD6CFHFads4RHnGIBycWEH8gNolI2H4tS@cfJA/lCGr/us1QIeRIfVWVpaAtdaTcpJBzATYPZ12XEVG9ccSMcpM6lQkjAY96ioS4c0V1jeXIZfGf63FmmfKSfHcmgpgkN5hHl5JOM5c8UMU@m9qlFdlqnkcYILhcfhXD@lhSNQLFdYLBSlu7hjNOFULQuer5zuujkEHTIhSQm5UOL2VzEffWeWy9Uf5JXVEDzJP8BrwMWF1NAM@GqoFPYuJGjtLrlGPQ2coG4UQrWaWPxicqh2vHUCCU4OmJzNpBgonncrq9mV/Eo@mysU8qtZeaVQWinkizmQUIVMPpuVSysrpWJp9R4K9Az6eaK83Myv1f7BzOe/@QfzPvND8ROqvWXDFDs8fJ28D9WGyWQ6S0WuyvnVyqgKBaGgUI00Ka5jj@6SoIVi84QuaJ/VHW7pgaKF7pLIqgvwYaGFEFuAIPgAZjT9M7EevXtQEQtz@JIFvjgnyXlghljoApiBYwtZU58Qtt0TEDhPZO7MF8bODDpP8PTQPmQBLWGwPdwD6ZrsxOR77dbVVmhNnHuphUK0kHEOdL0M4SXm55ehtbQfOx/TRo@/emzDNkFL/ekw64pxzaM2NbyssOX6UTsKXknk9DW39wDEqdXHczKq/TvDsNVvQgHRYMkB1uHH1k1zHsAqOz18oJav/NOIuCJIxxEB/Gj3@c5J4HmyVd/YCRXY@sH@5tQjL4DybG9r@8T3rvJYL2neR/Fua29v2iseONNYZPnVRAJEJPzgM0EfeqaWvvdA5NTDY2cmwRrH/N79YUc3na7aZ9BvZXyNWZc11GyeLZVkkHkFnP6tZkq5Ur5lV9fl@FFUjg2K0tNFCWaX6bVaS2FdVgy9wq1gkIKONGhOaAemI3285BzPw7shW23D1OTWoNMaTXyh0MBiDwbCA4PQaWvdHsi5W9MDCDUVhcH3Wz@QXg1@3McDXJ4Hhc3E6HPAcfFL67BMKEWmq2ypmC@WctliolgqruRh1pZPyNmEvFpcLWUSckYuyoViviQniiul3ApIRIjNl1ZDYZAaWiedBoEvSxI9NaOFF5Gu4Y2uZqpXC4X5zB9GWXxTXljxAwZFJuWKFxlIJ4VwmyvTqosSvosyg296BIQKa7Hw9vZGZntbktbRg2a6jYwktdGTL2Yyq@uSpFLMBgjtrCSZPA1EAZjLPZnM@oYkDTgCPDopST30bBVQu5QkDT0b9e1tzOcKPVlMD2DXPIZ7dM@zCmAGenI5Uk8l6aOPDuDqPKMVKukWejBPjNnmMRsQJ0nPvfJkMoDhiMNxDDteXet1SdrlnnodY15QxfO8qC/RU6ePJNngAR6UpC44ujbMoyWpCU7kRElqgas1UiCsDy48ZWe4iiSNOIGQRJI0JGildS2BKiXCMZudnR2l57bVLv@MbP5sQdEgRhsOtrabz583u92mPapvPT/CmBcvdpSr0cBudpsiWbMBHxPSQMx1fzT9gTLuNhqKPjfmJcQYUzGNUUPFsjWUj1Am8eliJv3GC4h5ATHzFj84Nvj0AbSJn/U@PNeVJsV4H4qh57DZlCrIo@7IUtFAgl2GtgtVgiF9pWWbFXSB7s0WI9FIYnQuXyY@VSiG9RmLxu4ylXsE6UTpNRMoFWN3o/NhNXMJ@rZcQctNdLH/VJJLeam8qDyNDtFdkMqgca9IsTK@oMPsRFgkKT8FwVZYlcrL8JSeSjlwDqOZSIYx@Imdr14@lVYRifT0aVKCkoAXQBRIKK2WEGFpFUb@yj1QwwXh2hy4aqMRjd6qynUsxmvEX@rDzs7OYnd8g5RGNXQrnegwMazy0jAtVvkEhZ/G1FZhgBu0XNPm@LpQ/09PM2WqJGRflCD3dDq2htII5Qc8xwZpNCv7pujQGR5soEON3g4YUmqdcugE1T964R3D48ZNfEcMnWWFeQW/94De6KKCMlgKhWpCFzpRh25qR8XdKK1k8mzis7Z2BnB4JhYPE@4P@myd3VIueLTA213dqK4DykzFwPP5KnqXhuFhqNZWXAVmRet3g3JZwN5XutVzRPAZf9aS0lntTLpkwXzzqxko1anRWls7/3wJCiHQcxRWqnK2WBmG6ezI6kolCvOPWNVRP3K18LOOhrzFRjXDFcQlZ9A/zywW5MRdspG81xXHXZJXs@XzwdJ5Ur5cXMx87q5J72vSJWaOeiP9BY2NIPIrEOY1Bx8kwh3tA8SzcpK/YkQuFmIp3OLeMDsNeo0A@xAYC8YJrQoM77oKOo5cylYESMgSfBOVWBTfD8T32kQjkdVsJBKLVABqEYKJ/WJ3xC0R4OHIE@BcGIuAdUtZiLdVdwBqD/Qor5h@Cbi6XJBD4ftQW3MstlIKhe9C93f3azVPq3jJRiMlnvS8TxjrxmHmlKYVFFx7WSRXMlV7xurVeveoXhGg9Q2a36RD7IKf4EqmF791nSa@VvuePy9wjQ6yCXHi0FJmei1eS9dqtYuQJElhyTOyR4t5mBSh5eCHMN32xzbuOgODbgAov0JyKWWuJ51fxn7Y1/S7Yi5ZI4U7Cl3tPhxfS@P6X6qWJmK1Dmh5PBQ2TOFEk6sLXQO6Zz4v4QxMZdZx6fvV74vfvzo9OD3YZs8y5WK5yClB2xieJRJyRI4AZZ@BVqAdbYXC1mczL/9gvKiEy1YktxLJTehzF1VxfjmKfBA9x1UJ@F6ew@zqMgaualV@Kq@WNUcsGkTLzsBS7dhTuZAtZ2HAjYWdGp6uzK6Ga@SQC6vhyzBHurIaAzfZu7NyuJYWwfKqDMmS3Ad8ng87wBTFVx8@w2xZvNFUy5IrnRYlXbpfu4f/2v05TCjvaV55T//4k4afew4A/wjue/hj/AnABWHG8Zc/JNf4/xr9bBzwQksFaIXwh2oNGvv7xveNcChcitTi6Qi@nVtsthDTNFTslg36U51l/Pt@HLDsOM6y7wPv2jLL12TG1OV0On0Re50FHbBUKhQL4dCvZz/pZZhULi/UWYRfpsNFML2m3ju8E5l4NRraApYXkpvHBxsvYcoNMlg18BWRbONgP4VR@BbD8emrlq4qtj4SrzEcIRSK7pONQ3zR@enmIaU5o3N3FEpTfpHL0m67LN4ikrhhciqHy0D5dGYlLeeZXCxnVsvZAlNADDl4zl64ljApo2ptmNaIa@7RjRglXqgjDMbtaTB/ctQye364RynoCP7ywubWqwN2sL/3LuWF8vCTnd1jdnywfXJWP9qCerzaOmZS/ZjtHkvsbPdk5@D0hNX33zGIPqrvn@xuHSOCdAhFGGoSnGC@Gs3WnJGTRjXDIV16ItgxW9eqOxmu2JaSxrshJ4MNfHWEiverT4YPDJiEtoNq@nF9gY/aDNEr7bYdwgN/WostoI6@sKzauCtW6mWcVZYfvP2UsfOLrLWyH1llrcy@kVtbZXpG/DF9pZ87YouLixeG5Mv/YDX8WUIwCLeKQ9i4TLvvtxaihRW2DHOD7EpsHLN/cLiQ8XwLZ0cnC7Ifd7S5kPU9u9sLOd@zBb4V37d9trmQ933r9ZcLhXGy/Y2FVd@3ubWxUPR9wKQLpTHO/c0FORPyiHVjau0Fej1WdHt3b4stA1CsMhGLRhh0TAUDIaIDw@G3L9C0aHn5tmcmSMlsjqag2@qXoD3wCagF1FLOka6XCbZsWvDTV/sADMlCvt6n2N1WQmDFe1RgVAndhRawQgtYIYBfwHO/CMcWqywbYxC90OEr0lF@r1aCSacOne77zmFrqC3UgBkSdDELnfKEFKp4m11o4V6gjHbIUNWhrasECqo0k2wpFsOjYfune3s8MxgXbNOOSgTJyCPNwWlagA2qCL9YdQjljcObhdoCabUglAp8417ofqI1Q9OtiaSAei4stADBJHVvFD3BUP1K4Eon4kUP33IOwBAN7gy4@Jm4aLSFde2qbosKFENibh1s8xriWmmVTbZyjGGmRCmK5pvZP39mnu/CnfTak14jwnEL5LxYHB8vaRVhYxi24B1GJAg6eE0pF5Bj4nFIDdWhuEC9FoDo8OXntL1S1iCjTIQ9eULlWANfKUJZYLo45ciSCIIIBMGIfIjML9oiFTe2kF7GrQz8ddVIRBxH@FWNzZF/xwRI1umCTrWq3wv95lwwYN5SmRLIIqrTxrYGdy7bAD@KR@DkBGtCN0kwL1IuYCTOMxJMTbAOBE/J1IZmAOeq9lgmeqwAnZFaf3@TtxC/UIXCeQDVGORemRoMhMUT7L7E6AsLTRtmbxUPCuQhQQHfItNEkRAc7vF0R5uUbJn3F2RLTP01KXe3yx4f8dTADoLTiKw4j@G8IqpLgbUx0Ax@gQz7bxXQc5bkyOJxAeFzmQDbmoRLJjncvceXX6jE1nQtFr@5FiiWH6zF1ldW4zerBQxrYxaBWoCIjwLeOEDTz2RrZuehgLGQUFBtfhoKGEDHvAR9fALBV6SHIXecPvnt6WGQLk93Zei30IJcKvAkk97WpLc96cXuCyEKgylBdoV9Zk10yQVw4VloVgRHm8vKyYSdSS@ZIapM9dJ0fAnMcwCeQ1HJwZABZ4UxSpCUg9fKK318uUmV1bcbu/tbJ5OxiC/lNETBe/iqb8ojNgkmCoTxThQ9Mb9E0Q4Sgeub0UOeR4Lo2Tg@Odqqv0pA@WJsbdwDpnUA@BE9YaIG914OEGqoLRiP2wkWPa6z5Rh7giVLMGErQM9XZ6GbjgqoHsyxPbCylFWGg/j@yZ4Uxh4ZmpOVFGXRGPt8cQFDamaVyX3rc66fM1ZzbTbKraKyy/H4OoiQ8p6A2eddkysbCAnsqeBtHnMzu8pk2IqdY67aA417mLFn8VO97nFso2HRO7FpmTQpcyr0tniULeJ@CxgXJ1Wbx7VIGhuRDzAUuzGE4XBOtq446efInhTrKVi8LG31W8vyJY12sixJXpY1ynS2DL8W5j6YLoWmTuXSNSGm5VoKHlwVkQcW2lIOMcgOhbiNJXBbVNTEF0q4sTLd8oEypdHAywMbjaij6h185fTAbsGQj@qyI8Dwg7EpHkkdCR2TkYI8qD9NRrQ1PGiKdzzCqDOFkN58XaW76aKUYyjkl8xxVYtKFSgGmsnw1avBDGGCPeGHZsUDYIESx8pCK95WsD94yM4nLvjhOAZOLzEnGMTzbKjPpnPifLaZE4f3uM1L4h1MnhN3NejPKwEIhgdixNHCOTGGeTAvAb8fZxxxeR4g4HmQwJeX0dj8pod@NdnigQuOiP4n9kAVt/XsHgRYEJRLwYGBtg5vqsC0LQ2v6Z5G5B9uhpTRYSxwztpnq9iYkxSnpWnT6D1MAhEdFKSbqNmw3OoB1u/kbDGWCCAMYMQL@PqK/hBOFkAKJZyDJMzfss4866fjo0YWnMY7Tp/CawKMNkzvxglM6xF4jB3DYuN7wAt4w5Mf4zPznC43RleeZRwKR@s8Nr88cRfWQ9BeJeRYkKC/afbJb80@Gcgf@@RPyrrKzifLcRkP@MsQMK6j18F/UkZeqSdzi31TjYNco6rXD7Av3lkSyIbfVTCZrY9GSCCfp7yqEHoM@EohgbiCiL5BvlDziZPU81KPx5/lKkvKfhou8ca9gczqgcKH8JaFRgOvJ2006F66RgMtS42GxHOggRcHvOCgKzobj0uBltowKTYqJRUpISWT9eON3d2kZkgJfvNxVXJc01YbeL2UlMAlx6pEAquBMD1Vt6qS2P@lOIxSSw/nUQ/kARX8ciYExHPZNSiT8b2jX86uFayS@RVVMqcyG9@F@BW5HVFueOz7sZxsfqmYl9EG3XuFF4nZqoaCht/pLN5bjBdETNxLgCZ9UQSer0OWPgdvg@BFokcDw0Rb47UK9HboKiNrn@TdkyLNXGsiejuaehDBmFM590mH9OYXRndmtVWhZ5F5KCWN70sUBUuJmgb43VPQ@DUT4wFt8u4UUd6EZ5t00Iw5VdSxYDEtrPy5hFerQAMcmhb8@tergNu/YAXceMUKBnmiDtx4vwqm6AiHuGoFXHTZCjyBvaXx3Y59Zaj1B2i4CR7gF5rcuFg45GNNaNSnyEnpxymKECkdL8mNCryxuFSWoOoOXewyfbkLws@73yV2GZoVsnQbMRYzoDrMQzr3xphY4rfQSAFFDEWzI0oDaRMSk7gSQmnl8iVMPgO844kYVJ@nwkxu9UREUJOEn348XgXuh6lOTC@QIjB54IUZJ@BWpuAb1ki5j5V9FWTcYkEorrjNKTfu3Xyw4EEMnqIWCz0yk/r/zTwp2CT/hU6V/r@fFM1MfX7HU5lHpjDfPFv5LU4L/qtC/18V@p@g0P/WtPkHVPJplLM9fkpd/6Ia/u3qF8m8EQwbdvcGTW/Zn6KH/ZYUgdVv0gO8Up/Lj@kCXx6fPTTZ4LD@E0fp0K/TJ@3C2bZZr9dP@rJ99LzerffqR3gVz3pmL352tbK@ebv@fL1d39zsvuhu7Kuvi/WVPevl2@K7551PH1XQ3ncOXrz/pFutXujtkXV7ph7e5tSiUx8MPu7ujNyd9dP@xnH@3eptZkvPd9bVj5u6s/nq5O3Lk@f54/jtxxeHLz71M33nsJNRSv3czqvCm43RmRHK32in7e097aB/3N46zfb3NrV32/GNzN5x6bWc2du6fZ/buI3nM@ld6@XB86PTq@bWe/1od@9de@OjqRQ@Xt9au@l2qbNxdfQmdJB7Le98PDjobmVLz3fSt5sdq53J7uh2/urt0eH66bud3ktlq7@dPy29vRodFnqvX9@4@/Huyllh8MpZiRv116@zL43nNzdbR6GmYp7YOfXMfC1bt7eHZqm/qr7c3@n2X9uykT7Iv4kf909uN7fW9Y@rw9zpu7PXtyvH7wavXr94f5DRjo@bW0rBarazx1cnK6FWP7cbvzndOi0qz9tnr/s3uzv5d5vpVz11v94@1K@fd3fem8eHe7v1nDMw5L2NG/3d897Vq@vNjV3dPLzWjfpKOq@ftN8dHIROX2jNTXXnrfOiftV7l86vX6@8i7et5ydXn3rXL9aPTw@K2eHhKGNuOEfNnc5w86iQLaZb@sejTx3zlXz6Ol64uXqR1d7VP7mh3KdRvrSnv1P7xot4q/t@@FFPx09leeP97qd37453buxm3Tj9@Gb76Mp@1TYOnIPM0YuXr5r6ddG9st4bx8dyK/NcvX4Vzyih4emOA22knij51ZP@3mtruGl@PNp97xQ@xW/OrnPq5vXRm/rHo0zz1rDeGvae1t/ItA@U@hvT3RoMn7dKN6fXO/rexwPnXejVlpzPb5sdZ73zZqX0Nv083rl@/nZdPh5m9o2jzkrB3n/z@kzTtnpvTz8dtfLbb6xi3zW6rz@d9rfiW3vD3ie1mGnqx@@ujdBp/vjoMHtrvNT67vbO0auCe5DZe3PY3hnJ9deqfGusbozym0O7kDvbfGu/u94xrPQ77ePgMKPexNvvLHfltdbstN5orf7L0PGL3un@4Zvb3XzBft43tPXDYmZ/b2djv9teeTnafTXY2mtetZ/vvlXfWieF6@zW@llh8@1xzj25fumWWjf93GExfqL33e5pPPRi0BusHp7ZH98M36/U@001d6S/M0ercn/jhZUdvqlvHXzqXh9a5r68nR2lT/fMaz3z6eT2045TqI/ixeGp2zfdE3mYl1@HcrefLPeF9eL18cH6i4P3L5QVTTtTro7ftDO502Ja69m53ULhuby13el/7JdU@dPmq5yS6/fizt51ur3RPn1zdq1f9V/2r1qhYslpre@@HyjmVjMrZ96td7by6t763omsnnZfHq9s7mcO37YPTz8OT9obbwenbw60zNbVi9Jed@Xt0ZvSy9X3J86Jcma@fWnvh4bFnOnIhVL@NndcKh707OPc2VXJff/yqrCunzXlF7vZvrqt2W@Lo@K19al32709VjPN7vPNj8pRZwsk6elhRskPrveHx6Hcm5P@zaq1Hn933Xr51pD14pm2mj75eFW67vVe3m62Vs7qnz4q@edXaul4O93Ut/PP40cbrw@vuptnn4or7cz63hvl7XCr574Lvd7RNq9KZ9cHw5H8evt41K9nDD1/c3yWvzkx14/Pdo6LvVdNu9PcueqBbOiPTq9uBzc76mpveFt82bt6o2T23hY3DGflMBN6oe7220cnL9/W452sWnJvDt7tW2fFs2H@VdE8K5kHRe1lvfN8@Pqgs5VZtbSzk@HpVi@9vqH1iyBTDvVTe@Pg9c77sxdWJpQ1CuufNsz86sf4zfBd4Sx9GN8bvGudZPtntr3zVrO3394cvn15XN@N7zZHzw@vlYN3W/nj/Y0N50V8Wyuoo53crVPfyOkdM@T014f7Q9sq5d5f73VhJDDbpfbzk9yZ4dTrndvd4vFWvf7cae6@UIbD551VGCPws3X2xqyGfs3vXgvxa9f4Q@G3OYT6TrdpDkFe8rNkITooFKKDQiF@NIh2SPPdx79OL4dOgpvs6f2g3MAzaIKyxtomKg8ptuvfhYqvQkiwvgnJNXS1TIueiFYcBmjjhE@HX7JX4Wk1eruZOrR0U8O3zOCN9zgntVV@JA7Ul1TowGD9Ec43XbXPt/5r@KIYcXUpXZLP38dDVyeGFlot5r0DLkUXc/pvhPsACoRldJN0E2uXJZOtjq50HXDobXJ9CB37N4VjDrqmoPEDs5D3GoqcyYutqaiuUuFO8P02@8@ZbvIr@L0ZhwLKxIhuskAjFd1moeIrZB3tRtVH9E4FtZ0K8R2fX7ULMhiGW7snw@j6yKm9oaBuqPbUBlCLJ/RWWtPLz/CikWfLabHEispQQ7GbmotvIW3wVzE0eI7enjdrcu8hnSIVC7RcMULNhi5eTYgTMUP0TaVCitEWczx24IrsUTVEFdXbbbi8bBFK2nfFuCeAedl6GLfW7/62UE/gbmvqBF4TaDUAWtGC9Mya/XcObXL0gSohvli/9Xb3pCFevMG3GE6ctHlgx2WAyhXPZ1V4DQLlFyWf3ZaJOwyg@Gh25PcWQ1VvTM7LEu17xO2R0No4wx7vtqS3bGPREZtFu1HOVy75DsIMbd3zCO6necI54UmgVE/GBF0QGyp8HvjKdHyDJgeZrS8i7tiqSgC0m9M7GTK12e@3zHsPtExTV4xrdFX4VlmYL9itQGPRKwUC9UBTll8XsX@S5ghYb0jqb4MdF1Sy/WYhALEh1mvmUwO7M@23xzS8hf2s0T6GefizLl03W9Fx9LK35YbXLeblxOGnsjpAS2IHd9aa9ohnhOaZaKUCILhPh2SCani7VQO1ro6pgehoU0@gFMC3FS8Ij6yr43Im2OOl5VktEjvQDqD5ReWbgRDq3C/WJc/qYVkI9I4FKzORdEwcbwsRONPLzDUtIEJHcBwMY8QjfHfqDFX4Ti@fixin03nmEv7Z06CnzDfuYodS0eyJIiSG3Rhn6FOF8wuNoDW/62BWY9ajhsId3NiEGvEi02CGj@FMi8cn2imA/FxDusksTtSOzokFMeTXSJBe0J5gaE8ctAbfiss6fAcXp3VoikRrkNHnz36HAa/PjYfe2UBgCf@dx8jgnDN5XxYErXh@rxP6booZE8WXqveze@npWCNMwM1bSxuqehQEZgNfKGIxCBJbliyLOwjC374EwdjYVHYhrxYXo5DqnODSxUv2hEXltbXoajJKQd8VYzG/M4rk2UDyQGIQ0rUai2aXozkv8QomBpS5SQQr8xFkOYKV5ajsIcgKBHIeMHAVg5B8x4qcaycRFwOIfbyXkzD4WpI5uS9n4/Ll2loR93gGAqcSZ@cXfTkXz0JijnohPhnD0fKIQPjlZI0AeS4bGEcCKFbiOUDBs45PRoxznYrwMw3muXI5d3D6rSkv3jkNb/Ch5Ph2RNU@L2J9kVP5pnSLgdtybRGIb6iy6D1V4zDO0svI5qAjUJeE3HoqHppK8PeUiUEL6FeZGhUDhyMIAsUAEcHDoyXY1WNjXfPbBzsE7pCBj9c5weQEK8I0BCQKSIwiJAYRQjTQuo1W3/LhYCguxviObz6AUSb7uOKM5wegnVDt93IiMcbJhyvcgE@8J4rGEE7fKCRo7O2u4@PN1hHumN3dfw5NuID1SLDxr1fNRY7Rr@KGYvB3V2iuBkUA2cYnNKKuvKkm88dAL3@BzUMu4Kex84RUO4RgPLHQDokvNLehmQIbJ6XHR6pLdKRXKfkAxVgF5hnsVmWKjuQY8VfAFvkbl@jQG6UmUoHDTygKiBRCmp0c1fePtw@OXhHlDhv1vcOdOmKGCWZLsduM3gmCHcQwVJ0Pqj49Qzj8goTmdVKa3gss@IuGEZa/XI4TDwAbFNOg0OkSYX0508/A8@B5CUii@NCgVDTaqjUHN@5d9cFEZZw5CHkr8lKLoVCUad5ISAPe7EjoydEaSjqipak6RsQFxqZ3pCgGlydpD986zDLpBXPUc1GP6hK/2PyNWrksvWYX@cgZWLg6rLalIPmVVkt16DD@mPqAUtU7lImQLAFCQcj82o/lBz@b4o@9Age9ZZAG3Yyv947V3EllEbRHTrufpOMGFCSOxdOR7jy1ktQikTN/6@@E6qhNqowPZcZzu@K5XUFuXOCyq2mFTLs8v5pQxOaRR/PIc8V1Y08z4@qJv5WcWq4Dnd7p4Q03ZAvhUocaDJuJ7ncwRxOy7onXZE@8XjzuifOVu8eVMkHYSY1MDDjj8VNMmNttIFt0xrZBJ1do9jWwsf25x1Bv0UMjJT/o5E0xCJ44pQHqtAfniU88Q/UgZyAmkIZ0WuZcZHdJg4qPLyoQsqRXnlhA16BTmMIqoBkgLcaH00RdSZU0HTFRDASiWBWjsN32OjlBjgczuz19oAuBMJQfOByfSuDH@HhGRXTSGwqrhBo5ZKyzUgTXVZNJSBDjdg3SaUDcYh2oeJo7vxrF2WqIynk6mcZPwKCoE26ZiwIE/QzzHgj1Mq/MrXegHt5hOEwcC1QsUxEnKLwTvaeHLCfncoHjvwdn@6xQGJ8Oxuux2Eo2Mz5yjBdlsUIp9JPsZGN7AudH7DiiQZGtkGdw6g66oKrr0In5o63h0I9l49PiIX@MKr5ytcxnsI4Qx2JocFgf333eVPEd37he6zJ5KKdCCyAUTwJvj/cGbwDsDhRbMVyVn7FEQS5WdjFDSog6rGo7/M3y9G51kPj46m8YFmyVG4AhpG22aJMk4qB00NKDPu1GSqDCcKPaeA2A5oqD/gskcwQ7cNFQ40zgBXrCoebxBiehEAnUo9HIwslIwzJSj5tehCtL6srJXoZKebIn05DmvYcVC0DkFaxCNObu0IIg8MwwQ/PxZfEyKq9L@sBj0T/PNDg7yPDJqTcPF2j4GDM789cu5xhjiLtawTFoKDYxESqq02XMOwNHEsA7AtXy7BAciB7DSxqeCBefjSIF8c3sGreFM5IRpEXQKEVDio1ch7t0xMVpFL3gv4ma@LkKvS8mdgaMxIE5/3ikgECWj3EIcTZyGgL7J4cYBnFAKXhHXU6P9x8MEYd/3g3FN3GINwtHd0zMCxABn9eS2sXLz8@kza@F6KOUKT@SNl1SiooF@vJ8MF5lAYa1C4BBoUgeeZXywE4Px@fePEAqPRmkHiv8RG5fW3iR3QzQBCW@sug@Ie6FrW4eUkjcN29UvkglttUINTPQPlxJgkYUjEA8S/1emCoEDTypwEvXDKTgOrOXxpMkFCMO/c6KHAHlO5az3nFgT6D7Zs7xud55FeWc7FXVqya1IL0NWtcsGhon6yq6RbCuSXm2squBynqnjCcqKxJ59Zy938EAR0c3b/n9CzigSOLksvRdO8G@a@NiiAgJjlEeNebJv8mzzoEO@X113CP9@vllpUOzvof3VbF2iKI9yO@YDvFmvE6OrwOmIUBGcNOoeJvreaqFBaHOgNIzkS4bE2Znn509FJ0OyGvaqo8Xou5lPUxjjiEsVfYDx0ND0CfVngD2wD6TnMcCxHxYfCV6EDbARUIyT3RSjzswIh4X41l1who8PkD9ICMGsQjZGTii/Gh6kimzpRhhHB8m5@Pwkojhftz/K8GCjB4sCJKD1ojEWOevGfErEe5/05XRse5mCc0N9C4rCz8fhSIm9Ld8xtMDotZYX/BnB3w@ENQNhKLtKYNo2AIFHubG/Gh0gkHuD8KPbxj5yBf48GgepKQbQILJ6KqJoEDiJcwGpkVWYBIzW0xqHaKoxdtkstzUkGQI8bHzajyxzhFZOpvEZUDujMsztZpAx@iQM1njKvzyD1Jl8T5rmqcGb//Ahl/GyuOS5XieZeHhYG@3A6HQ@pau8pM78l6jfrDrX23FxPvTVcfEICdl2t30rXatpTlg6FhcW5VUB9jP8ZIqHtPYOoWhDC@cclPsWOWbFVDvRbXsA00n1UHsAybCG7AMAO50QOM1Wiq@CsO9xf0DAoGTChYWohUH9HDTYCPTbI5Lr4iTObwACSq7A4XvAmEGTXrZe0txHXWkpjFhuqnDT1/Ba4nTMCVPYw3TB4a6B6mPoUuoqSvlRgltBgpGJ6encqUr6EJJtB1RjIuvj6bdI2hDcOkV6k0T2sbfnyomCXSvomnoI2bgFQBdBd9jzuiNtpAVct4tVJN23IpFHdryoNI8YiVTKpCwd8QIR@lw/E6lIC4fC/FXn5bxfIdjIrvYKu1NpeQTe1qm9mTwjjm5iYLP8yfDWng515f3afhbPNLpQFrT@Jp9H/P2eND9X0D2h3Z@pNNoHrV0ZcSkW4UuhGYbK6uZQhnnWlrXIDbE3oKX6AQ0dnVo4QtEcWMAjuNeWl29UXWWw2Z8ozkDADx2B1ClUNiylW5f8QCjuTLDbAJ3dNH8euJE/zjKNPXJkA6em2DjGTWeTGNMHmOjE1xiVEFiimAxLqgxkFrw8xS3PJumxcrgaKvNQZcGAzyX5aXA01FKookJlFgt2ow9hWcZnlB0LNIy9GPs/FX//ircT2Rq7By6@SXzFiikSohqAV2/yktf8dLjyIFggRUdGLD5qgaMCMusISaj3EoA0DiGRTmcw@2etHjugbTN3QO02lCGfHOxF4NVtMRFjw/uKVlmgT0lIBLwvilkTLoCK532LCOROr4K1vOsR3gsWY2i3D02EfFRb9knh7d/ocN3n6zRnWCM7vAkcsYq3q56ucLuPUDcA4IaDu4sSUa8nQOoYdq4NjPekQKkl7xZ2GNoAwXIfQGSGg7ZDMelQDX4Bu9Lbu0SKsh0tHzprWFBeDVT8ajB3xztt/94MesJb80FqvgivYf6jgl1WmrxhRhaJRELTBNlxcFL8AhxB8clhvgo5wcKmOQGYU0ko2nCN6jygnKbKwgL1DmTNKQk2JB10frOp08JNhJevPw8xO83ziRGVbniX4isGoP@HU5GEjzJwEog8D1TQdpXQvgrZnQ2z9zv3TBKkFhHQR4iQYFB5144mjbuMgkm31co5xa9GIqLeNAjZnl/7l6sCwPxlc9hKkL/l3yYKH/XlhI8P1wyIIfsObKXiXFunIh@qYcj8zo6TIxAdDA8j1QTsw50C@M8eUeBKLqjRKzTCAGDdtiGguuODaRd1LuBjDWGVZggNUZVtOHx@79Q4eXdgi6QQfgyA8BkEgFhhso8ZZfiicwg@obxOMbDpG4yfmCVcZbtpZ@Jx9Yj/Dx9EP/9@JI8okNjmGiMYt6@FEjRGC0TCfztKfcz1aXi/Qb1nSnvVH1n6OHX9wF6@PWdpedPqq9vMX5LFYEhhh44x8Ep@1OYUeOb571Abqd4yjAwMx6hNt9Npx5Y@AKbqdT0UoLZ1KZlmQ7e1jy/BDzPOYWg@EA45PmU51EGN0yQ09x8JBcz0PXwonknxLu4baK@GCU3vuWPj1@gT@rcti3GaApAzCWy6Pve5JQfMoiJoSQY5IlEv36YFZepXJ0Ate2a9hdXWSCril9wqiifgzFK7Nc@xrg3gCNQddq@CKXxkiChYmxekgHqHZhuOgmGzU8iqC7k42QqpDqbm8prREwtdld6mhCJHWmXz5LGWrcUWGtqkHQGdg3oE/481rf3DuMeg/PGIEtvJO6N0jAV2@2QtW2Db8Rmh8I6hceeQIV3e7Y56PYYXhSFOiDC8i3lHRO1e9QuQavHVzsO8K6asrctLjquvm8/TrNTi8Ekn87PY899dcg2UPFvjtCWzG0B0cAwIXZYLSx4utPC2KS9QJLeB77khj5ucRhnT20WKMAm8gMU4RVa4iD7I2KnORl7g1hS9jUQSXFdtW@5qFlrvApY/XEyC5dhxglRA/Du@CJlZcEHnV9YzsaB0lLpgsXdA1aZV9rM3ELSMdTpQjZVNPVlHikctyJO226gOJg7lmZT/R20n58rX72Gef8XWBMy9bgyQXAqTHJxczQoO3g0r4@Xj@PNGpxTYQYOKPdNG@eGo8RczLdoj6PepdzC3IumyggXT4ni9GA@e4MbjeamphW3ngJNRUcHEBGUgFQrvnaG62X4sjBM/Yqmo35iPgF2SJXDe2d5McwWrjJ7iWcpYZstVW07qLIqyCtUzigebxDd1VslbGtKF2eIMFP3RK9XHLJH02yxp7X4qYyNQyyKrX4caDafbGNpUtCWtO8HWGGjp7auCRbflzPGntSMJJDNcJNmhzkfB4qNJgfTZvGIExIyno80R2InzrQeJQRUZQKYOK86q4QEgFH9xKsgp9jKs9ehqcaTebRZB18fEXHEqyGEzQhpG7T9oNUkxUBe@QYZGJ51cUJXcwhPYPqdYJ2BjrLYtFIYh5JwsrJBHyqWzcUqv8RwopoBzwQQF6yTsQGMYhuK7WOI0jAuRmIuab4MXpqBxqweAE5yaH@OFaCvTzQg5QTdJpZ36FDQ2H4B0WQ/jyK/OR5MB/da2KqYQmCaTCxBmcyipaF4FqthGskgZg42ixjgECz2te1X/X@p/RgqQAbKHhAwePwdLYwtBY2VVHQx@4SeTrVERhZVATnQH@iuYqjmwNFHv2tGCC3QOyCF7gxBI/K@E95JdRynYXx2lsaXAbDd9AFtd8O9CThRB@Gd3StjjHQiRA02XN8U4yzTxTEYJ@G9NwaXiaInGLcn4nBw9PYETMXglQlo6cFtAi6d8UrwbQMgOum4mOGmKJ23wU5puQMSoj0TN1fgntIB2oNwj4eNR8SoSVBgY10QuWmpNs8MuG1kDpg3PgO/jq/6BAE5vmtTg0zF0Ef4UTZjtZDv@UACeBB3ABVuOeyqgTQgfqHgAE62Iyi3N7w1VWGjwMGNr27hGx4xB8oWnohb42fgxhn@5Nz4KhzafDFLxD2VLoPXCkBnC1jJ@D776KKY38e8if7U/idSmT1blwfLGUrs7ceVBNpVMWuW8yawWoU2WkS1Ku7UWMMTFtAvAfRcu1ys4loL37VBtjNsxVtgEFWxWz2oErSXhgzj2kSnttYmssEcDs3e/lXmDgP0VcyVK9DGoN/EK2k6RC//mCate6CRHECiY9Qxynl89FIjCafFgZ8vcKsn2Y/bMb9v8axoXoKTHwD07Ug4gooykf1SEAb9451NPnU6UeFFU0gWyYL@cxGI15SI@@hnorKX3s31/pQvW5nGKD@CMTY2nk0dCUODlxvY4nRr2td85QjNbiT5XUUjuzeuBfINy5jIs@jhIr8zjuMrGZ5xbvxaE@rPOLD0FPfLRl6Pm1wQijo/0MMPTo0JzNfwKuNNy/5u5AznLRBhLW6BSoso3BnF0/KVSy7Yfebx1ly5DZGfDcoEj24JWleDXYG3tTBl8nNttt4R2tUEbwhIwREI7ZUcze/CJOnlkSQ0BMULz@c4VPh41QOriONOyf@nvWdbbiO57ln4itZQuxgQd14kiuBwKYnULhNJZEjKaxfExeIyIEcCARgzEIGlsBXnnkoqVY43duzYTuViJ5W8Jik7rkoe8r7@B3@B/8A5l@6ensEMSWnX60pqqRIJdJ8@fTvdfU73uZgpMxT/uZ1q@CStuP3NilqNTB@Ow9QR1qGVhNuGqu6iMm9gfbLI8FMwVkcHcHizcaMdg69Ta2Ii9bvI0mrCGl43YvK34B7XkSW9cWP6OqNDY6HVxMM7eYuoWS4Dkju0MuAS00ZMylMbY5eXfoKpilTy5HAHcLwLDKYgzTfgq3kZ7gc5/VwvF6gflPyAaMc46Yu8@wB9J627Zs8fSFdmdLByIZ/eC1/vJUatQK5errvWuItNwZd@KBMaqMxbp9zs6i2HVHP5wZ9HisBJ73CMOHj95wxtQeVQn61WAIpMVuQLvyxYV3fiiF6qUXflHRn3QCw2ZLWyD8qFEXaCHrwNdzYkVb07ck/gz4GHLer4WeSX9Mt3KbPNl4n7e7tPjnYOGgc7X9k5ONyhkqTIrw2Kx8My3ZT55@jcuy/xZv2IQ5zM@yMPznE8cSjOEkrgh@1BEIiHIO66II6/aELJ5tjNpL65Lz1Kz3vqu6N1Ln/EzDwZ35Omse@hidAYVZWgf@csgPPzsO3nmPjhDCSHVKj12kNPBhwXKoN7JmzmnIP7J66k1oAi0hKEtGzAI2XQDc6RA5TSRPSNGU6aXgdWs1uSOrYKGq8cQn8J2iECMgCQj1q30xJFvjbXKgy8CzwnspHYVg5nC7L3g4rY52q3qVqxzf1CHrLZG/RPMtJ7gtEC4tzg0CpgXO11NcRkFARVoN4CegrEkeYecYfKKB@Uq6VK@fNzaRA@Yv@GvBW8gUn@G9p5z9vpJ8ZPSjLbVzEADB5nFrOhi4RNSrSgS47WFDWoi1W0JCt6M3PydGtyiX75N2xBnmJALlu38sUYjX@@9tzXNrP@zD4WvngznEQCjljlKPJNVDGdfX4GO/9XrEZez1zkKiuKL00nkk0nZEC11zGeyC5mSfsYOY/dPb6wx6smff3jK@1uGc4oxpOpXSuiaKsj2ESV5sN4NFIT@XpK9BEN@oha@a9NHT69rwm2AGF3k9WOX6PXhnFEpKOV19KE14F6rlBxN7X1Z5H2q3pNtX1UaR9NkfcML9JwzcnmRlWkabd59UpE1MDZ0oV1fIn8pYa5Nm9RTuWNyziljC7PDnVnxiVj6u98KZhQWgd5C2SMLA6vFQ0xJ6nVtEmUcJVaRCFeylE5hWs2P34xtfVwBMPLUnIiZl7iy7baizg2GIiKzga0PcjF5yiCMryMTUMZnRo1F2mVyYU2ZxOiX@D/v1hbaRJkA48vjax@g0ZWX1qNfGk18qXVyGVWIws3y2N/VG55/TKwZj1RPAfuP7MAC2p7T7z/3r0jcfTejnj49MFvi6/tPRXv33sCKXti/@n9R7sPBPzfeXK4I6iA/vmKO0KVewFTv@22XbqdX6pUVgRhngtQviIOm2fivUHbfQnEs@E3z7ZO@Uup7wabXGrnpTuaDvg5aIjKLIG0mqC7In5rUjdOaHHdAko@w3dE5csT20jePH2@WSLbCwqHrg24@W2PeBDS46JnJW20AfADSAU0TX6SJd1pfFonpqVTEnLg9M9rjyAwhY8Pxb0n2xjpc3v3aHfvyaF4uHcAX/e/hm52xPYuuo25/xSzCPDx3vbuw90H9yiBG1ApCbxbI4P1y5pQQnAalfaL7hjDg/VQKpTfIl69FzKZ/kBZRfgiO@6H7ns6QFL47s7OTmvkot2@de/g3a8gV@N@XVgWBrk0HKpLC4RbFTQagdpkFO0aO1NH1rJY5Q3pbCpuYXYtQ3dA9LkgFPIcvRN7rrAe4DUiPkhT3Gxm2BRqqOgm4EZUyhGsIygCQzZb2CCUm1Ab3R6o2vBitau@YNEt6ZgV5cgF5aXVJ6QYnHG33@YwuioB6J61uqnaYMQAeCEkExgA72AwIWi@cHfxkkSsSohxgII/JNzmhOdnw4fnyDWigatMuM@BQNZkm3jeaEoxwFHT6/M8RsyaeHegGClUxCd4dJLT66krV1KJA/5fvrHhqyxAWrALdmFlK6EifHYDaoC9/bTZDXxhOzm8DQYRxO17rKl10muCuEf3wiM0WHqJagRU7ZqDP5vKUb1iOCkQpxJhWlMRbYcuty0Pfve65aDk/bkaUW@POo0KUzL@05UNuD/XgDdBA4iK5n6BboWGATG2hGbQlaRs@wOgSBD5xMfRqEaDzrjtRgpIWcd@7n30UU4OciEsYqj4UOu0hh2GesCHkHP0QUVuLkCIIU3JU3yN4jm0oz0I34bPUBlihA38UA2urM0UHlSNUhNHVor8fEqtrSYZw11ZK1E86wbr7WuofUbR87fPZnn0TNJCMVlLcz76c0YlBvTsNEI3L12BikXTgFrCwR0y4d7xsfDL9Q/WnM3t@8@KH39YOC6XT3hbaHb48YKVEvmZhURyWB5ad5K0AdVKk0gz/riFpZU@I@@WuMoVMmBcTj1gvrcaNZ3H16rz6X2KlxVNp8RXrxwuVSR7EyIhjCQT7m4FUVdVFqjMschJBOHeCY1Fz7oqpUA49X69hXHtcRZqMCJ93EdIvcYMq0b6NYa3a3zQg50lI/k0nm6NP6dikUuKoh/bnI/yB/Z9J7@ZKysoWkx6OG21RRcU5mpO9mqG00vn1Ry67cvRwf59fXRrl7aOj4fXwrZ9KbbXalsxn46LjyUD1/XRfnwJWj7c3ggt9L2QjpgPyXlsmtI1cRZuLSiav6LGD@fmjtYeoMGzFyOqaqRGbeN@Dz3E2XwpDk2jAjkTTcgQHR5t7xwcCGsHb9nWoSzse81@m@xLcRtE3DeVpyO2Q6bNrqSZJh0mSDNPKmXG5qXRai9bzImDl7JVSB6kIMdDbxY6ai9IJhNpHcEnC7EQaHjNG6IauWjrLtQe5Ncl4lkdNaFEOGlGBzOJ3Vzgw4ed7NMmE45bgXlj/4U31MyMO5HOuuiqejQ1ESlGGI@D5gm@fCfP3/vMH6@repjBcr8@pg6jEn4b/eWLQ6h4iC/FpegMXjItakpJZ4WodEGNHZnlRTnsz05QOhb7TPLCxrYumWPZNOaPbxmR7Ig/3cJ3/qnMbJ/J@061xVPKhjmhufDQs6NHEDCZIAaLLZMqoPjxTB5hNBr6nHQ0Q26utVvUmrpqJUUzk7hr6UBvAQe/eju@PcSrgt320qqKn09VfEpEajLibs3XoDIB8@3V1eWrcMd7oYoXPytuPkPi@2dwNnzZNFD6U59UhYByd58UVH5IAJcMnQNSYMdWCyZWEFidhDMl0nc6jMz2QVvOR2iLB43Ze3pUwPuieK05MYm1LRk7n0gmdgKZ64OxhHVHedXMjf7s8uruU1C3K@q7@fr18WJDILwPn/2Kw2QeDIa4VQIjPmqwV1QQydd91IoLsAQHH9Sefo0YmFsqjmWd481t8Qs32khzjVvB4AXq9avImTK2mYXPUKWz5vDiFV5wvaIrU85DmwBZ1iuIreeso8KRNbc6A1Ii6OpQllvcymgabPMvG2bwzXVUH6Q8BjAeMB09gNm3swLknnW8VVChJrN5TgP@RCcVOQloNUDZQ6cvcjraJXjD3lSnlzm942LgOZ26IbGcN3XEy@ymhIxHyMxaEpjuar3utEHDrrPf4WxgY3TSW7IxIFv2Bjr1JqeiTpVKqsuy4zDpmJNAktJJCxIKDyYvMGnJd90XDZpkGW0OEGYLou/1jktSf@odW8qOOWnCEfBEQnm338nQpFDMU41KHQlb6FpWklB9yzsukQKl3IBQJgsnlhfSlhcWMIEh3Qh9yUTFxagB@Fs2QjbVJF6sub71HCl85PrtsSt2Jijjq9iIiirJMciC2HmyLfYeioO9/Z0oamxxA3kUKqUU9igUs2wYdUct2QJM@GAcnDY4UX2N5567nKtQ8HcN1B@MDCD@Gs9VFRCKY1yW4uJV55Wow@E91JNid3LHctJVj3UfSu3BuB9cvJq8oumdAKdXAhJ4R8xKeEnwztywyJUoOWxFDvQWh2Ehka9sKLcKYS2UQrVMpG@OgbS4jq353Exiy@j9E6YOViZt0mFATtgmcScYIMuzLuNbwnC0T8OAm/SW7QjbjjcMD6VSaS45L@7owI2uGXE3Wtk1K8mnVXI3rIQpTOMp@RhHNKwtJzoD8cp7pSoLDxU8@tfi0o4ebfTdLKfROGJo2UVgKsdGNr9KGH3uZKKf5hacnEERjTcqXzd4QWCQ93A3d5jGI2BE33NgenNQYLyA5uBoFUQAeZnMAVL5eYyN5FaGSy@hSHKLw/U435yUWkJ0CUWSawkbHZ2KcK3HZqM9AO6MA5LghwYIgsb5mjhzQDZzFactVhEvKEmRxJkG12nzn1xCHWqbZgigx2P1sXrMpjciaxa7FD46ImYLZOeNAcE9iNyp4LFmplfj6eaRJDaN4nEIo1ExYMAZO6mungv2JBJJOkdLLV5WZLQlo4EjryWPRthyjg1QIqEU0GIUlFdNCAugCEJcHJ4sBiivxChoPhnUIH6CN7HG2mqsRg2aTwY11scc1mIS1ihoPg46t6/RRhkde83QLtqXT14uhY810RlVuRO3PQ74pFFOK2ANBbA8TEZLQne8Ey94R4SMFn0qQXuQaFfWpEdslQYC/uodzfpQAcVqm02Q1YYIcbcweCkvoWK@jjLZt5Ax18xjBJ5DXOP7uAFaJwhzGgR7YJINUUyGFGjUKaZYMXNouNQkEDUyRhKWWLiArzPkfusLFyzucOR3q2DlZhY3qxbZRaFPKlnKRxsbaixKwaDhicSfmmw84RgMRRRHKUy65CeCYxzoVLziKPQGbb7sLCCumhLW6pCOAjg97MRw4GvKfF9UQUBzfHU78EFlHgc2IS8u65SJQwlV8zgWr41DCWzzOIrXbwfJU0l9eevaOFgQTMJRvjYOpMD5MbUWLgDBjH9bSaQWGQ80i5KpzUIrShoaZzPyrRXvixJVBdoLEoYI/CT2LakdkjE3ab1niEHXGg8UOubHw/Z4JW3CUUw7d4UvmKtYMje3Xli4pVS@gTVWXk3c8oMOHASlbk@v74TFHxPRY5ckEiHde6AQU2qfjkBEwtksSelDMSCEE9rfaKBqVqNBN0P7B3vvHtx73Hhy7zEKUQu8R@H1DWrLkLpOpbSE8ez5tqVBOkWOQFUL7EaG9mEjj9on0ezQKUKRY7HUwoUBN7OYgcKaHLovKvXdc/EQsiho/RxOhCzpuxmYHpvaoDd1q/jSyoWQ5gmmeiXltU1oCcEwnciWEIyRnDGELS7/rM8aKs/6zwIGbIk622T6x2Z7n6HhklFQiOLLZ8FX3FELdUmK2mkpzyKq4KPsRs6pUOVC3qCHGIwJ/FW5LO4rp7jSfq3Za6PL23GXHN@eeb3mWavTLA1Ph5mu70j3NHa266OTywwqU@0e7RwcNvYxTtfOA7KcwJ8a5R3tPt7Ze3qEOYeQtSyTdw4O9g4apKB@8HT/CD2GxpIsE1BiCcFkQgToyd579x4ZMPzdko1kgxAf5E34I135FIQ3bEzo95TMPAqsCtGgIDxkpoJFKa0gAu/MHYxV8Db0P6EO@AJanuCjDNSlohqTQxobrz9lXujrdGZAUTtG42FAoKQBb8dGIhctwTBn/gkWIF9EPvDtpE1f4htlzENDvsHQjpVFAxkslpH2XV2fVgcuk8Npv20rdNKRZ@HC7QMkvjZlx0G3uJad5dCr5JCUhuKFs2U4OcrkHDWbXFKOoNRKzxhBjMxr11pGGbwDFFmU0CSElilUgF8QayKf93IXGTNAlMyCXZXjR10Iw4Y@CiPj19ww5ojdmrKeL9SPBKI/SQscTSP8dd98lCICk@9TZMxRR8tzPWb0V3WWb5htPTs2vU@Fdt0l1B55AA2@F9js6IV89oV0J5@7ZAMamBGf8WgeoJdvY7LDVCHTuB/UYKCC0VSwBaEf6OGCnh/j74l07dpGBRobCC5nwloW57I7SjQS8gMGIDHP2rTWQzc2bJagFYcZYsOEqCZBfGBCLCVBvDQhlpMgPv2EQbyunc@rydsUS6urrM0cmc@E4v@mixeLCnZDqUKHhQGfWVydxoxkh3FI6LyD5qDmmQ3IzZbdvrRlUdSf/jvgNnHJUkWqhBt@SbMvwfzz37PW@YbuGqP019xDY4NC5kQ@ebEJM94XPpAkrpokbUnj2H5yCTbLUrOYXPa7IUV8kEI0n/40ApNMNt9W8y70@KkXrhth2Wpo1RBH8B/zCJzXQdDg8mp9kbdRNuDF7KV1jUX1IETAIMsmyFIcJKnKV5dWWTHxVROrrJogletU@enPZJ3y/EqA@KGGoL1WDmYi6H9FFhqp5kOhJFCfIdGmZj989U0FP4m2wSyWBL4fYqcix5e3@@ffiLc7LJkI//uJxEkFTPpS05448P9wXRzLqTg@ZBTFYuq4ZRkin0@F@PRHYTt4eOPL7LJF8vM/vLp0Jb3074alw2N@Ux3czDUoZPEtUKsHRTOpaF1j4/mDAdApCa0xjlG95owlh2exNBiLdqCqs6XFWTR7SWVPE7OXdXYM@YwZLMUloX89Yow2OMIgsUbhZ7LyZYZLZW46JteW4w6Z3C4z69LAHMZG8zjSFMdgejZjAsdiRMiYRy1zc5LZm2WIC64lCj9@c9Q87TcxQKs/6JdkBBBvUN45Gzz38KAaldHNRem5nyYNfRbWmhCQHOeg@HoPFSqgqdKpCOt@s9yOgM12e3w27uEbmiPlKnSMVC6jyzgSBPvjM1/ixBP3/tjrQQ8c5NRCFhHEvCG0kk5hYKWvVX2s6qRq56ssl1lvvERu6CiJ2tYeecOAKnPmZQF0@UQMKlThbRiwioVHA/ULQsSuaB3Zn0de37UNeIzi6hWMBPKLkHe4VI0oIz4mBo4CaoA8GZ9FMFzIGSfdGIdzSj5a/NiVwhKOnIt0I0YuRgjR1hGeL5akDzpyLYNIpAXRKIplqbCS41EiRPtAnmdRiJXCUgUrGmIWuSgiz9Bas7zZJbdFZNRKOAibhqZZAI4wRC/HdbMCvYMM3S7H@uXffvJ3Vu6iXFZpFFPH6zdBZqCIJCFW/Ho02FffDfQon0hbxRjuvw9xM@qO2/bOmhihJjBQA3GlYIYJRMwXQGjotGrQg/1mcGIbvmBUhUhY5fK97W1x9N7B3vtoDcWXCEQFseJIBOvCyvOwU8lIvlQMRhBJCfMwj2XFCKQaMQ@le4VgusfkXqdrGxpYMFrf/GMaLbrLH6CmO6/LGELMttipD94Tom6tiVZPhKJgnIdv/hFjHgxZezYZ8WBoScKEj0MXiF9dRdpz/WKI5Pp@8f0/o@qkRQnwfHivcmZWncb0U25dXsgSzRarx6m9ilRDg5CK@Moh@taPCZnPQbrVRpi5Ye6KGklyt3/4V4Jw4OMDzJ5RUkTw5K9E9G1GpF8PaORS8RWvxPcdxtfx6BXARNSaRrv4GM7J0giNhmwjuXzF8P3i@7LFAO8F@GZySR2LkeZmEifjX82ZpbJyOtLm18CfOsM/MJFKM9c0jHxQJeL55GfhMjW7ya6Tmb5vGKsz1rTEDn/yn0nURzrmsHrQAzijNacqca2ktPkv/lLjn2RuTK4gmF/@7fd@FPZxktqzSWp/vheupsl8LyZpbb8R25K@ikeGlZ@kTsVPo9VEVu7EMb6mIfhJ2rhPooM9SVvyQPp60U@uWPZpSL6tkOgFP7lyyafh@o7ClbjY491KWe6T1GWusKcs9Bj@xZRmwmL8F3MxTi6b@dQ1n04Wf0PIkeFD49G5aSmXJYdTIdZ2Q1TpL3rmxb@b8daYux9etYWMiwMcFaBDqSlCewg12TBX/kU8pvyM@ZowtSqdLageGbVUZS0gmjR7fkJVjvO51bWEQwfiXkItm29WSWZWLvddNrofDzsoddD73RlJHiN6/sPgAck74zdoLoHbBnGFrW3IPUGdmnxMLzj@HPkgOvI5pEQN9ADdAXGD/m7o7harnELyxo04lt6AWaIbdJ2OolCqICIliXz1OFGoYDk1cSH8k96BWLpqsXSFgyX7SH5kw5wrN@9v/UjvSHqUBlHsMZT5q3H@o5wGUjGit3Ly2CF5unTUTuSbFqSiqeoISD26/9ncLWLVpfOSBlga5u/@iT7oXB91WTvQHzR5JY//GBwTByb1BDT2T/5ICOzcYrhlpNb8p2rifd6h0irHk@wa9aRU8@M/sJC0kweJs2tXC1kSY6qMJXafiKeHOwdi7@nR/tMjvJAxHSNqGTxd0GOxm/dlEmCjlwRzsmwNxPwlFmeNPCYvr@Dll3LU/T//Hnaf0eYdq2IZw3RpuR9EylVVuUvGiKbi2iMkx2euPF9aQOu4btlbx1mTIwQC9G4/wPXqu/BBgvHFBDt8lmcbkz@bTJtSt6yY8Vxj6j/PbhmXMemXCXjU4QQ4VYHz51S@pIwvhjLoymqKr3dO0mse44deKJefBPpFU1DkZjP5wvf8/LzUxfBU45FXcn10T@SjY7jy8ASYhf6ALjXRbTYQntcG2RadF47bL8JPxXaz/7Lpo4LMOxNUiXbuvj3lv5m0O@LhyRmH4njTe2Ih6La3MC20C4Cs0Gq/KHTPOzWZwYbBWuGEE5H7GakvZ7765A27GmIQ4D27zmr1XrQHPeJ2rVYPDjIrrJp7qCCn6qv8PvTYMEZdIk@l91NBTLPNihQCHw0oBz4CV6Wsi71JfXocKT7RxSPaLD5HxLwUKSsEYz7rcVDYgAnnT8JKVbX1iXQWr03I8PUBlUIUJKKZKpiIRTjmTFgpfhNfqDANIaeRNLT8aTtUWo03f4N5dBRhAE0MYcBdu1z/4Fn92XHfd88Xj/PlkwI6OkLoljRrpDElnz38GUe/97I3HPiRpL7rB6zgUlFJ7VNJDUwrrPgixyqmcQPN0go3XjhoqB3oUCZu0fcC25NmqqSNc0rP21bdCseYG1aXjcGR9pSSgUzDhyfD1N5EdGwgwnTdJRWJL0kXynp/hP60FGwRxhwdwPSnaEaIgRqiS0XGMBWzaKvwtYwTYNjZB26sKyofpqIeyzK6OZPzbzb/5ms3vwvrIrn1RLC8KcaUxiYubLiuXC7sEXPTMeYVWlBebPbQ5Z@10yf3NEpxMFdbLCvTFK4HuyCDzhqT35aOJ/gltS@1ULCuKcq@YurwsuR1oYZUa5qEr/CUrwhBlucNhCOIJBRzZbGJWQwkXd446Fksqdi50cgJNXLCRRh6ktLIY1kMA3mabhuO0WlbE84jwFdljV4SC4XffInxqdgV0WJZ1xnuOUQFysIQJhTprH2cWHvdaLSxacUQICHOIei43ea4F6xn4htetai/6T2Kh1LtUfxNkgHvFUBgtAXXWKnM1kQmXyzwKt0jt5fwqZ6xqoVKoUr/KvzfKqhE9b86n1iJQlajiZVC7N@vJfEYRzZZLKpWVnBDzvxqQQynwemgv5RZEPrMFnRmoz9CfkF97vP7sN/3hkM3oDBH4sTt4@M2Bn71Bnhjgc6/MK4OfH7hkn@RdYVc8FNs47nfQEQNiag0nArr1pYF4342HIwC8VHPa6nPGKP89or65k99dCPluy7xQD4wQfKZG/V9j0bT3WCvj/cSZfSYHAz4c6s3aJXPQJR3R@TK0Yc1DxDeoDQa98vkbsrtd/BZnMwQmi@gaadQHXSt0wCwBnbLziHl@S66p7SeTbpdi5y3uL3OoYuMG94eCR1JZbdDfEfTP7VwW1sQT4AJW2d3K8qHifbSRSPuiqx8jCv2OJ4zaQxkjUhfqPGOsSxJM8NCpWj5Xk@u/6wSPUBDKStHbJmdoxNxEITwSpVTFmDFkEgJ7CMG6WPGGM@KsEcYItRFyxLZiLwQMoHaEX6VlYYJVJE8n70CsIfYK2VF69owrcwzVtfRvSfelTnVnN4pPLSTqq6tY2wO6gkOKE6TfBqurmEOOaj0BUacY980Zj/yjmwJAPKEUCBE4LFH6JGh9ZyUSPGyDg4PpL@SysPriRa6ROtRjBe8v@q7JxQlRZy3PA4F0/F8AsCS5ZOPvKEcokKEVFvjE2C1aS1QZBXP98fu6p21FWoQxTVSoJ1BOwK6VAbM6Fq2TI07Dc56uhd3g1PRc1@6Pfb/xs2m2C@8KInObLl94nXz7RyRDgxlpKcwCvbdAqdt7zx8dO9oZ7sgitVVBGcDVQ1rG4PL2XnKJwMOSUZYhJdvqXV7hYnc9gvZrXI2J5u@ZQ573mywQgB71gjluKGddaiYvJljxCAydXCvKuh4izq2G@pq43LDpoxHGLXAUoOrVv7CgoUkjXUtIAlGNkcokwsPDfgGG88cUOpeASMgd7cGCmEYSogo19q4WSzqNbVOn4qwsRaLm2xnbj0AOfyFyB6M@5HdNktrpymysMmhtzze2m5maV8oWTVx6mTf8rM15M415/TSHucuVIi/fhdbYfPAHQ3uT9X82WOltQIDkqtXj3M5mZD9n/8GsW8WmgX07CB3gfz1R45yCVviTX2HPWjaWb4NhmIflQJ3EjygzTVwgpou0Bp0piUKSdp5AGdvx/7IrGNo5y5Iu7ntOMu5C6hyNEQ7lCFshu4RYMzVMK0bSQtFjmfP@ugWdxHlr68@fvQeTPkB@pfyg/oHx4u3yoVsFo540kByMNKH2N57vI83CaNciW4UHo4GZ3JcRk1dSQkf9tFymFpfsLBrZVyFsHOeuIHsvX9/etQ8edI8A4m5CUMQvcBpmlo/GOYedfnNMXKs6ORauYsTh6BOR263xpzQzHde2ie5WgB/Ts0qVqEKZ2mJsAdQyEEHArFR9/pwWr939PiRk91oCsTqJKyKbL6liQMIhQjGxiQSaCOkg@F0kaoCttskgoGffNbajPZlo9zczNZms9T2PBo0O@zxKxsScMceFyTFjZz5Ka2NQiqYDl0HE/hoe3fnyCpAWZR9MZFiHE1p02JnxI6qg8kNdwo6AqeHCOM4K2@/TWlYZOw7zlKlkkP1kBlgIx8QgJYX1qg2GzWdjq0Hsjn0SnR17k64LmJOlkpL5WbfPwd2tFy9Xbm7XHlnMMJ3g47rt9/2YQtxmhhS1gumb6MhP6mTnQx63be7Xg8frG6uLK7tefd/56t3D29v2@3WbwEPaT33B/iAPxqaDRg1z6X2H@yxozZTFzWiDzjbzfKw@WJQXulU2muVteqdjntn1V2rLK@1V93lu627d@@2uytrrc7dO807q@1WGd1GU5HSGSkPWkz@WG33etWmMWZrS5W73W61evtOZ/Vu9@5SZXl5pbW22qmsrHTXqs3l5dudpbXW3dblXFvYngxssGrfxbMjvgO/lc7cZeb2dlk6978';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmQ15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22/!]sss_ 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^' 2                                         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&   11/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xflosgem 4721en og _e25 $91 <>60or 709395cr=B1+R(1)u8"?!"&&1/<>ca g 8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201 )#s>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42709846#42709846) by Potato44.

As with Intel 8080, boot image was added instead of COM file to not restrict polyglot size to 64KB.

Some techniques from [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom7/abc/paper.pdf) are used in this program.
Polyglot has less restrictions than above paper:

- can use UTF-8
- can use self-modifying code

Boot signature (`0x55` followed by `0xAA`) is not valid UTF-8 because `0xAA` is a [continuation byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout),
so to run polyglot in QEMU boot signature check should be disabled:
 `qemu-system-x86_64 -no-fd-bootchk -fda polyglot.bin`.

QEMU executes first line and second line until and including ><> without errors, so x86 code can be placed after ><> (`\7aa*+42@n;`) on second line.

I used this program as the basis:

```asm
; fasm
org 0x7C00

mov ax,2
int 0x10 ; clear screen

mov ax,0x1300
mov bx,0xF
mov bp,msg
mov cx,3
mov dx,0
int 0x10  ; print msg

jmp $ ; enter infinite loop

msg: db "202"
```

Its printable UTF-8 counterpart:

```asm
; fasm
org 0x7C00

rept 0x1A6 { nop } ; beginning of polyglot until and including ><> code

; main program starts at s = 0x7C00 + 0x1A6 = 0x7DA6
s: db "202"
db 0xC3 ; lead byte for 0xB8 mov
; 4 bytes above are harmless instructions

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; patch the program

mov ax,0x7D21
sub al,0x7B ; ax = 0x7DA6

push ax
pop di  ; di = 0x7DA6

cmp al,0xC3 ; lead byte for 0x81 sub
; int 0x10 = 0x10CD = 0x3232 - 0x2165
; create first int 0x10
sub word[di+i-s],0x2165

cmp al,0xC3 ; lead byte for 0x81 sub
; create second int 0x10
sub word[di+ii-s],0x2165

cmp al,0xC3 ; lead byte for 0x89 mov
; create mov bp,s by patching mov bp,0x2121
mov word[di+m-s+1],di

cmp al,0xC3 ; lead byte for 0x81 sub
; create jmp $
; jmp $ = 0xEBFE = 0x212F - 0x3531
sub word[di+j-s],0x3531

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; execute main code

and ax,0x2121
and ax,0x4242 ; ax = 0

xor al,0x34
sub al,0x32 ; ax = 2

i: dw 0x3232  ; int 0x10

; int 0x10 changes ax, need to reset it again

and ax,0x2121
and ax,0x4242  ; ax = 0

push ax
pop dx  ; dx = 0

push ax
pop cx
inc cx
inc cx
inc cx  ; cx = 3

xor al,0x44
sub al,0x35 ; ax = 0xF

push ax
pop bx  ; bx = 0xF

xor ax,0x343F
sub ax,0x2130 ; ax = 0x1300

cmp al,0xC2 ; lead byte for 0xBD mov
m: mov bp,0x2121  ; mov bp,s

ii: dw 0x3232  ; int 0x10

j: dw 0x212F ; jmp $
```

`xor ax,ax` and `sub ax,ax` cannot be used for resetting `ax` because `0xC0` is not a valid UTF-8 byte.
`xor cx,cx  push cx  pop ax` cannot be used because `pop ax` = `X` breaks Trigger. So for resetting `ax` pure ASCII solution is used, it is described in [the paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom7/abc/paper.pdf).

`0x20` space is not used in the code because it breaks l33t. `inc ax  inc ax` = `@@` breaks Japt, so to set `ax` to `2` this code is used: `xor al,0x34  sub al,0x32`.

Patching is done by `sub word[di+offset],0xABCD` instead of `sub word[addr],0xABCD` because `addr` has unprintable low byte when program is placed at offset `0x1A6`.
Moving it at printable address would require to change 1L_a, which I wanted to avoid.

Compiled code:

```
202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmQ15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22/!
```

`.` before the code is for l33t. `2` after Shove is for Del|m|t. Adjusting code to not break l33t/Beatnik/evil/Japt/Whirl/Cardinal was hard enough,
so MiLambda was fixed simply by rerouting it.

New version of dc has a bug – program `56pq` [returns exit code 1](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/UrKDw/38A), so dc is disabled in the test driver for now.

Useful links:

- [BIOS INT 10H 00H: Set Video Mode](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0115.HTM)
- [BIOS INT 10H 13H: AT/EGA/VGA String Display Functions](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0131.HTM)
- [ABC compiler](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom7/abc/paper.pdf)
- [x86 opcodes](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html)
- [UTF-8 at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
- [UTF-8 encoder/decoder](https://mothereff.in/utf-8)
- [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/)
- [FASM](https://flatassembler.net/)
- [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/) – has disassembler

Answer (score 8):

## 215. [emotif___](http://emotifuck.rs/), 10356 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNdiD4LM7@g30JkfqKpHhNUqR4EVlF3UqqUkkqXUpVJbFYSTJJppTMzMpMSmSp9KHds/BOj/3g6fEaHnvH3fbsYL3AAGMs9sGD8WKB8evAmN/w@WlhLND/oPecE5HJ5EUq1ddt7CwwKTEzMuLEiYgTJ06cE7dsynbv178O4cUODW3U1QyHOYrtsLalXitWkq2P2DNZtXOZbCCAUDWrO@grumOXAiEmMabqLbUN78wxrhRd/axY4J9hzLSMriX3mdOTHabYLdlUbGYMHHPgMKMzP1qWsa2@cakmMGZf1bsA5iiWaSkOha8wdqprcr/ZlqdCclMJmhaE22xT0b70vzisZfT7st62ATLP2CvDshWEbym2bWD0VcaGW0prCmkBQGVLNfZq@8@ngoqMPYcsyqamDJnctB1LbjmqoSNN0ux4//T4cCqGJLE3J9vb074Z9jJh6Gx70LqaDsqyU8uWNXka/wqrDRxj15n2z7FaV9FllkkWk5npwDxbt@SZKKvMUuR2R9WUJFQIS7CeopmKxdCHdQyL7UKWtEK6kG7UxjGTLYxbGAdOoy0yLZt1psqTSQPhDaun6JDD9HSg5AVOBWS8gLZKCcjWiEXsnmEBH1lsYCttdmNYbWAuXRtF4xCfDT@zpmwr@RVEkPUQXOnGjQ5M5BhQtc2RozDd0BMUGQFXmLTXmGasTA59awe70/55ltmb9lsFRmtddWbrMlNgR4Y5mvYtslfq3jx2zqZ5Q9gw2lAbU2ESO5TBi5KZJHw2M9kKWlC70JjZpQ0ZayvM1lXTVBweCLyiWBQMsZmm6le8gR9aRnvQwsbn9BRIGxss8oMdaEGsKjOFmEiig4WIgzgY5ODY6Cv@/NpMV6CCbFNpqR21xRlLGTqKbkOW7SRToRA3qqaxtqJBhDH2VpzZBlbv2Kupyb1kKxlAxsRUWP9KYyprmSbjQVAKyNJ2usAUpB77DOFaz2ZDs89stQ/BTsvodBSFfVbMHkQPtI0Ag6tlThXLe1tSAEZXXNIoJggEJI2BlAY6uRS6sWQgrWULGjhqHwirOmGbKbKtokCFKLait4mqpidqDSZPsDy7VqHBQ9EHFuG2FYuaHOGF5mkpgFL2qjlyY6mOQ62G1dihIlvsxFKU6KTYnUgSEjMwBQcLkqRKXVsLbx1sh6FyeYykbEJlWtmT1y8CMktW2FKjDL9KMFgObO1vstulC3RzKQsMYFoROcoq3zM7dXGhwG8oNVNd6y4AWANAFY2lDNNJyQkTMphwIIMpGZ3oSlxnkqbmS5itTdWFj@U4VBtqA4QPexOnkrUGloU9yZio8hUUWjP0LtATCmsNdKSHzvJpqIKWAR1BnCnXQDWQvFRHIBeQwic9FSrNxirxNSzeHxJBoUcENhYUddO1DW1AcBDTdpCXgSoQFTHudtgb1pFVDaNAOKLiubYUe6A5GGegt7Hmob9T2knmZoMarAV8fA3JyYCUPID1@752SZkCYKgIg4qKQT/8wZ@2u13AU2u1QLYJdn3D2kaLem6ZMgvdIUOGBYGqUbYALo6p8@iQwLWsqW0SELI@EklQJijVG2OgtZkBCVo3KrTSnnwNLRsaV8tROJPzzj7O@vIVlyYq51woeF9uQsVSApQ2FTvBnm1ALbWUQIh4JtEfOJ0CS5hbLGynPkSeliJPFy8UyFw0GV1eSqW6ZWC45DJ5wVv4Ic55U5uQlLYj24baDpgjp2foGZZosWCrYpiKHglP4AjHw1YzHE2ilItEy2qlleyoejsSXgNerELC4Wi5VWmdq6V6eSq6P0lAc4NosLkqkVY0GACRQ43iOtUHaZ6EzuFNQrh8YYbdQJJjcNLnjYSZ9rvmHiFSdpAvDWQQkENJW1MUM5JOSlEUEwg3t9wYMK@kUzhEgUtqPRYOhWP@ohMGKOlEQbGxnqgGii3N7GGnBUTRbRN6Agt5twU9NUpGW3VA44yzJvE19SIgWUgm3ihhS8Eu3eMjapK8yWH8BApKgWHchCZbstL2NWQQAtCWHXtGGmvGDSRIecJuBkSHjonKXagaiMwLUuMF4SmRz2SRuKIB2JoKKySaKjQCbG4g0wXP@8oG4NkMhwFsvJH4ZE9fHgGWFu9Wxw2GqR1oS30QD6ANtRSUOSB8FN6hYCIDan826NiobacTmVxuso3NNDHHStUS70FIf0492JKw8P7GhIKGdZQbpsl6dyB3Fa6JMbnVUkxHCCooie2AKJrub8gzITrPpN0LLD2bTps6EVe1GKeBQp7XnugKZZQuQtFPgDqjMFmYKqA5WiCWtNF06gBwPZV48COCTGTgY/CeLLgaADCZMlRaAwekGjDwTU9t9YBnMXc6l4u8E5pOHrz8qYNkT3S8pDEzUvVJJpBMeV6YjXtRJLBGZ/FA54qoqhMeVPl@j4cxy3Z/DmLDyyJ0BD7fZEpOAu99BWff0I05SIGQHloEmQzh9QCa2DEqlNBxuWoXNVZPy/SqCOoMDYE28l/PcUy7BP2E6vQGzSRwSurEGu06BzoyS8qxRqpjcHdTM5oglm1onyk3hVRr0FSHUwUiP68OL@3ANShgHZtVoOf@NACui4Q7NghM8t9AYF9QkAQ3oeD3IAASUBIIFenYJIq3Qagcj/RWJJikppSERheMsyA23CCYO0GM5dFlw@ijFGJnpBigpgdmn6qjrSBkPol8eW5X58l@0uvC4eSloeqR2/Di4mK4FK6CZF9cfAquNXQ9RVcMXE/JlSAXwiXRRTHi5MLQc4qBfvXw3bmLeRitY7UNsVf6rJoR@bxUytbj8rkknhl8RkHUgWQD6AQ@AE84WqmgMxoNVm@goMlmZ7L0Gyidj1uWagoivJCvZf4uqJAlMqh9E81ISyljJ/swTfoVC3pBUFpbvYgVvjhPX9Qvbi/asYu7cBxjR8typQmFgvQi/WTXMgbQXUbPV0oJqR6Nnmehk2xWwunwciRSSGiQkByNfleIxmRO7UhYAakdubgIA1EFfc5bPYvwDeOZaNQjFeQDO2bQCSPh5G0B0m9G69FYGOJGw3EwMSrhMFCmhUSwqdDImRMEOjh6yQmzEYsFiA0N6wp/M2If/JJgYPHo28C/G8eTZm//CqQra9kaqiIJi2sj8Jpa5p5tengaV4ntksaqQ3cLJYDetu1ZRmiN6wPSn0m5NfwJkTmIEOSHfQ/KVXUCBhF31CEYCNDuR64ihP036kIbYHAampI8I9UkyKDhoNmrJOdqQ4e8W0m27DEPgN4DTlOTW9CwJ9FdBNkFIAQ@T6Xmh0TLM4inVSWyar5WRuhYWrKO9GurpLUPVLuH5AXNCk0JqwNURZUddAOFqLbLWtDnd4HSylB1uA4PfHSMUXZkOxJFrbHGtS5U9lBjwEy5YwDUnRstsHcU0BwwlBuPbEu/Vi1DRyIntwA1MHwZ62AK@TzyAhvVaruZzfvpOw85UGzGW/LR1o91mrgtu8VSuqEZXYMtAwCyZjLJGXtXx6ES0PkcMC@ZrX4mAtW6hj6a4kEFu3sbdUQpn/W0bxkhUwSfvARZw@YXegxwT5mPd99vQQ8h5dJpyL/7lqbLK6QPy3QZ0bPFxgBiyFZDvsGafK@YvdHEgBLyB7cigZ8MhTdMbtfL0KFCrkQL/0xR/Y2c@0A7d4Parmte2bdIQ8KhDL@VMVF6UAahnYri8GYDJQxNeaOvS4oJpDMVPq5fFFwXqQm55RlOiU7fcOTUm2TPZngLoL6QUFnQToUXw6lEAu9BCmKZKku1lesUSimBGaTySW@gBJRWz2DBC9Bd/EBBEKE9UMITUAjFIjXPiyYGpwOOMQB9sa1oal91dmkgTdNRKRp3@G4ojgeOERyqihMQlsxYcONg11iK610OvzXErs4OKPRk@webW43D2slOJZga2FZKU5vQNtpKow8qrabYQTZ9hdiRAshE/M9X2pFhOBXOCFca@@oVwjhu9L3Nxt7u@lHt6B3PBKGx1f5AkzErpaUpAIx@TMFue/WNMHYso@/p@raoiKUskl6ZmE1Aw1eErmDoQMwl@Pzz6N/H@YFkK9BttVjC4K@epwBcRUCcM6DesRuLISTNIXieArJAKHEeIWk1Xc8ienozCBNj62N088LvjyQw30rpO0Ru6wPb9JXsVpLI/9rpdFAf8Lwz5H2VwEakjb2z5M1nICbH/gVZZoLmAnv4Vggfn7mYi28maC6why/H8eGMx3x0UyHzQD1keUKGMyRzcU0FzAH0MK0SJv@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@uCeZyoKkyEYZcX0PZknFmQ9Y8x3zUqNOwRKInW33U5UV1A7viDdrbA5zHc24p2qCtuM/5iZQYEXlyOI/pap@15kAT7NTII0@MrDfNkNtEBm5jqQpFsrCyeTUoQ25t@JRZEEb3JTRngJCNZ@Sc3sAZ8DtOwn2tGlUTf/cRYQI2nZObkpIybLmpKg9UuyVfDdpGwrzqUqExa/k5sOPyN3E8K9HR5CvubKBzPgF4ES2121Us93kf2E0PzAayd1I39HiAM1zVipGyLD@E09L4/T4QdxmM57ifTqpGt0dUtMdQxCItaCRIWpxpT/jIpE4RVpObI7T7et/OWZgg6awgZyqtWCydxU7Wm1YZz@mb5v3xsWem@MXi/Nh8jp@TZJ7NkuJz@wk@5kVlFrP9X2nk0HWpfVlLZNo@571S3B1PHbvmgNIgQKKlyTYwkyOqQ7mG6qPbQwyOvVEL2WrseoC9x9lxZ9fum6gRrVS05JahqTY2Z@0@qTk9tj1OE1dZ0G0cFd9mCdsmNdjuJTzXfElgtBycJbmH0R4h2fgEBU4B@TgnadxHtJZxg797lYueca3w@/zO7fPcXD1CRiU0Ygm1NVeAtltf41ScaafbfDpezc2X09Lm@ov5gElT4LG8bKuaYYNNjveHSAHatW3z@3wu9lNNlfUEDVv73fOjiUyZLCmG6e6pS1nrGlq@0E3JcLu3wgdWByW/eD5W4nkSS5K@LrFcPcjQJfG8V9Rfpayrr3ECjW1bOAfmcz7Qz84TW2Lu5P4Cgv2AE9vzC7edLlDMZIoPkNxXAVardyOP3OeP6E3uo67bm5gj0qtBzcMIxQI4HIvr2j8mtZWHU2s/TiTNoF39WiF8lXulKdB50X2mSlkmLX1jDCmdfryA6mgDZaDMlU8HzUsFlzY@YG08PlNpUYwlMZSYAuLhQKIH9VlYjY/KNfbb@PaggJE1FRr5V7WbufLOBF3cREP7EByH6JiN2NUH5kTlTlhr@tHDlOuZbss22hOZxJBvlUiFr@tQE@q6rdDvPtV@q2@AbWz0QW3QH1H/AimNevD7BGLyGSsaE4Mjc5P3JspBlwXVA2pUvbITOC7@OKGTuc@gJ@BiMaWruuKM8H4fpecJ0aZhaN9SMyBL2yotYdYSuGj1azU0o@aINRNsPHRh4zBIs3PfoAXvZ4RxCdRDu9l5wFL2D0U9YA3ODKs/0Fv5Btm/Zl9CT02jQrbVct33MSQNfkjJQnL1QXbkWqjRVDSZP4b5lYfwFZPZB/F5WodQb2lSBidy@NTNeFYtNCV6zBEQS22DbdJT@gq9PqDUy@3Lge0@7gUaGvibE5xM0UTEPfFMFdq6jveJaSKfNuQYOlhTjmx1FTRHNJwZFb73yVd3fmMucXf7clfhOxweEh3jUQlcTMeNuLFz/vhEia9vaUE0Pv3/MCtAw7lSRrb7nIvw1agF9Tnof31UbaqNt3D086uNOpmaO63zFXVP7xk9vaf0LGoc3tt9zQM40uF7Ux4qBOS/J9tXuHqQ5NHYmuvZfupqhqY9hrooD7l0NIz5A7NbuPK/DVG/Ce9IbkKAeHx1xA66bCIS9d33tZ2eMoCeyTYcw1QS9HYfqIaDPfw@f6x59yBsszNVsdp86QOo45C02tQUdqNCFi5t/7zz/IGkpmbIuED1AeUdKOM@HzM01TKsr457dGXDMU16NExtYNONRnQTtE9jXnG3KaePYQbV4atOOMsqXaPZ6qlfy1JTkR1dvUq5Yzj89UG7VAhjKrnKEpvondRUoJU1SiITVPzhx/jYva//803hzC39xsCyRl8XDJMz/t5QK58hQMd96YvJ2TnB1OXjsip3@dAD0xRiLvdebiIFGpXlhJIGrUS6dwRoYgWZkF40qXiP0jNVbsqMbx7tW4YuxWIAGsRTfQsawH/e4MV9gnBHyDewCiM7g64d/Trj9tqgU@FtLsJaFzdr8ZkkWzNufAPN0PRlXTzm9srerONDUyC5B@dAkikx15lQBveObmmqafM7S3Qyc7HMTt7PQo3mW7qietpKh09ToOtrml3fsHAZPagQiZal2C0c8Ubpy6UiFzm60QUpnNDYGNiFnVuE2fUC83STyR4u8XZf6cq4rG5PxRV2mj3b6QHm6aUDj0H8eiDb6uuB4ShzcU4vIXgMyldyV23tTNSCi9ClrliDxR8TjQC9ZivipqfatJrZdcxvOJzNaDZ@NnB6UN3bVffwQIhPLxKLSllil7mLTz0HDutjuDw3rUmtU0zE3yvoVIcGTMVzbjnnL7d4aBThZtA3B7Z4zE@9j3sT/CPH/Svyt29UkIKJTyB0WU/WnPmjy77BU9CnRE84dt6nZb9XNaPL3hfSDNQvEHCodN/DWOvQLx/KDrQAfQ6zUvqPnLfEsYkEV2rsT8AISpYlVF11Hh6HcRwZ7CD3iQXiqhbuvUnt4T357FsxJE7mU2XvQYkPXfqopYFl8zWow3dfgVA2vt61fGXaBbpKQx84Cdyv@FAXkX@wiyixYSHv4wEWeb316jTqskK31@JrGb@iidkKWHQDWxuNXfdO9s/hMBX3ad8vZGdjuKbBptKRB5pzhDN6j4lXM00NRzZApm8a80yYwxF0Md9kB0EvMehvKi2cCXxUHvaNV6CeQb9lglTtHyk4dT8lSO6PjFH3jJasAc3aj0rumNDPK@uJbCrrUOfaN5aXY9yUHXkeVgVH/zpfsd/5eqQj2mrrbcqy42ItMfipltgRaifdbdchWndNW7TcLTsshBvHBqj8OYaVZAQXicixWDQa4JFwAq2rA5gLRRtfcVMc31NrM2hjDsGqHXZ@zpZuh6V0SbpjFRYsBVm9zrHiRVu0toYm7Vo94tHPl@R6ZSmcSISXwhd6iaXDHriiQTcyF1yegO2o9OD5HZOA6TJfXY9ut8RlvunP7tGGWjCZ2mB6neo0IopmHN@6xvdFnuAKnb/9y7bYZ9xVoLB9FVQ5IAhuszf6Ss@4ecrTFalDA5FxnzLigF5f47vmEhs1Bt0R2Gh8e7Fxw063Twpi06LY0w8vh1yH93LBKxdHCXHLgcMrj@fGWz4uEvZiuYUC4Tfo62AVt52enWTHKu0mGFjjxbvgQjDdsXBooB1nu6yt4MII2iRCo2GaYVzRbi/Myd/@Jd@qSVtFxBJ@N3naou1LEXeESLQ/stUyBpBrF8lnxTIESASJDDrAAMeZGXYL5B/FDRS0hxQ4MuHuoKRk@DbKjdoxS2yxMB5XgBuzymonslQ7ev7mPF2vfM/6KeU//yQVvRWEC36XKObtYJy5IOU7ZCx/cA6Cx6FhFlwaBnmC3j4aVQi1G14fQCKZMxlupXF5zDBM0WpoFzxt@va4UZzGEkE31bO7lbJPG@iJYZUb2kpJq8x1FGm4M123oYHBa5RQ81ZXWYoM@HBo4thhOUgQt6PK4OJb7mlnCW4LxChLQ/aF9ZDJEi3c7QBvnJAa7kTtV9bdpXJZ/4LG1KbSHNAinutMMpOtUHGWGpW1KrkspW3gjvDzDxfDTDpxMVzdqqdsl6gXF8Pv0pm3QHXDglhPUtjytvY3b5eS1fSXL7Y8YsHgXbjMF2CCmFi6Pdw93Do@qZ2cHkMt3LniZ9uw@vJY1iAX0f6FnqHRXnugi6Uq9jfIH@8NwCMRtiSzNTxFJhoN@BfQE6igdTARXOJOn2iaiP2V6PPi24ovfBZAyLSOylyO2oVuAOsQmA2phoUfmHhiABNxxa5n4jIVZTw2II8wuMx1jiwlUgVZBYiVAGI9klTs/sI@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@poPcM65LRdK6oc/@FN@VsuFA@6fCfcwvQ5vvyfeOuD@fTdEkuDtX3hvGXj7OX/7kMIqmz2gQiQvDNh7d00AXz4LzpQJZYJ7NBaVxattrOk3u4fMpukUrMu@PPRVE0oY5DlVB3qpfWCKa6pjBOcpjKtwjCdy/gZYBPgK@APVG9RoKD3FqkfwmIJSKoUZxzGfJC21V4Z8LoVOLfg0wNN6QAlL5XP5FSkFmUxcuwhp63AXF3tzhNFoCWRi4Fo1Kx@bLdzDw4I2GJtKJV/mvJFakj9kgx@9jC4BbIAbCucM4uC2Hy8GhFVFtMiSHJOiGBU7srAURpnWNjirgTYYIQeARNFbd3dIgrppCFIBH@vK0CGNaeQaQE08lQ3HgBV@ZpOLKAGIOG48U2a6OY6Xb@N2F18DTfqrIXiGYMcIVgrOY9bzD@zCudDr4mwhBoz3yzmsq4P7n885cIhzFm6mnj3pJjJ9Tg2Whj071g1c5r8NuWWRTCqTTUn5qI9DgwIV5Beb@hdACY0bhEVLUS8N065tbO2@ODg8njmxhSDD02BhFq6uxS4Syfh53XOEvXxPEnV9O3X8an3bJaU/V@OVMAgxXg4znc15qU3n9J7Uz/i6@dm0KWAmISn9WMQ095zYptVis9jHoSkf4AZftjuTaiR6e3deX6te6KGZ5L/MO8UqlFxG5gLXhU1nWIWns4lZ3HV3A5zg6Zh20t0WlgmOz2jzNrPx97H3/WeueGdtjg9ecfcdBGjj8nhzc/KeHQlQ9mSKJ0WnjvCMufkFWeNmVcKsjhNsBWZWM/lzw0RZZo8FFTvzPCId8DEk91BHm0PaJJz5KBOdfuTRzIM7cTFi0x8fhSLOAOlB7jS1GbgR29XdfY3eVvWkbWqqE4kGdAExvcNxFtJ@8EQRD0yunA@Zt1XPRp1xmKSx8Agd2HVTD/ADWZh7bkqMjl45HADdDg2TjUfRNhXXdQQ6Fdsc8LFRhb0Y9AGuQ48jBXsLBbSsBEQGeobdrJzjYSOCEsl@OxcZRpM9ZdhWu9DjRKJxEE3fSdL40BYZTx0Bvao5rwQ4LGX2ZCgDVk12Dc88GUbXivQ6LiAfT2Q38731egCQYdRmtMRHLsKnunu@FlZ8iYXjHmWa0Xg4ybglJY7OohUZNBCVZBs9XL9KQx@djkoqm/8oBN6Zd1Srn8RSQTfDWeg5rl73c803nZ/jo4x8LidVva0MI3hUQamOdAL/8M3ZdTganGFxOsRHHNnSnj7Nx5WFsiOE0vgknCl5Vyx6cm5SNBSLeNwBbvoEowRSPHasPXCCihDp9GWTRQZ0HJLNkoxeIxcRPW47VpQlqthd3zCdxWI0pgEPCgCbBUE75FLp3IkInh4YSVWgktDX1tv4@Kya7FxKJuvgpkSibAnHMzdAm8KRwGgAbFSIUiK0oF/AXwlzxM96TYozX5co2QCdSAJQc4NJTuG0B8gXoAWVmlWf@E5yGAsYTtVisSRqY1LaFxnwxdocgQho50hx10YA@opde0A1lNEAtWEpbRXk5bOXiq4rQCDgmT4ebSsPgMmsaNw9dTk@PhWRUgjxLO6IbYCQ0cnTErfCtxrOJiylyjQ0Vr4DtebjBeo1HaHZjFL/fSqZKt9GlrTKKAW6ZrQaWepVpFh2ORZb0pcjSzpqW0@e4Ija3RIoc40kGKhDAEosadEy8DMof5Ulvbwkr0WW2pXMMsWAVzCRbyHC93Yqebsk36WWnoCyFAcfiwudyJJNBxmlk0npDvKHLWQpFQeeucUTeegsZUx@SY3FMA/JpQZm4PvUxXGMus2L4xQN3pWFLZDq9kVzm1LFvJqYOQOaE1B4l7wOK4cdlljS2XCBx2clZueF3aP@8YRf4sJ3Rut1FNtvfAUnQx4vWIScRpkrhEyEnyQFBBxGgIj4GpejURAmv/51SMozFnyaz0aM2NNcuhwL5yQw08G@Dj0DPTy1HLSCtxebiWumdDL5T4lzuZP8VD@8Ojx8G72IsCILhzYOgtJK8AMed/24a5Vl7rnYj79CoeVUIJRalp6splIfP34EiwOu82qyCuKDX9HzRLh@HlllrLq6uhzPF5bjz8INX7aikUwmesxUNcUuVNNut@Fn9Ojg80iIX0@fUlpg/sM/434ifeFwXxBE@Ia@Ee5azoXYxaosL8dWMs/0cjKTzvztXy/exW8PG2t/@zv9lLKIjwN8/OzuFbqPpdx3i4vfra@vrMSBkNx9@P7wXa1WW9mM5w7Pc09XEunFtf/0fy4uZjJrmdRi3balevj86m0wk14JJv/2L8KHh68btg2EKOKVZRI48V6An8RyOXbFPsN11WH4T@7PbZ9bRnez8xlPjwJ7pULCJhzOZcPHH8Lzq22RSdWnq//lDw8@hZxQNZM6s@DphD6F8oUQd4ID3rLu23WoGlpDsPxdaJSqVCrgXP0v/x7iV18AHgwZrcGtmnNx5UehaqJCUb6EqnlwSJkMpPt//@QngVB1GPockiQpNKK/BrrhKjyRnjB0pIKrhaBhPMOj2fEa@q5xKVKSlLlw69NX3Vi1nncPcEO9MsPn59W7x1VMcAM5HgtXhdsWXn/3f/zdH//dH9LfH9PvP@KJ3/nFZx83GVOgB8arVHo2Uw97U@9HyQRcSa91hPA1IUoWKlTiDZ4rj4VDPscUHbw7EyTx3r8RLhByj61FOVSfqIyLkFRYOXg2fPTFxpl2aRsak9RLnE37uZXhvTBXFrBvgQuEvq9Ujhz8e9XEv0Mb/9iDWX7g4CT2FK5F@KN/uLxXvC@Sj/AmkNlr8TeQvoHQeei8Xt/R8e9Tj/4s/Gt@wr@9z/j3ycG/kxb@HX3Cv5PP@DdbmkBobW0tFIsdgcoomPYx1yn8ksmGePOYNxQI/VYvFoDmUI8l7u7Okx@GsXJZ/IMeVfbe8OIuyFH9LpFY@1CNxc4pZ@dVkcW1xMpB/uBZvQp55Vmm24c1wB5bO19bSzaq1Wqi/qF6vjYZkyLXq8@exbChPoOI1fr5eSB0i3VRwdsy3lo23jPBYIpev6Bch466GAihjlvkqm6Re9AXK/AtEPp4@zESexp7mtbS12npSrp6ZRyM/w8OhhCgDtOXhpXupXtSGwQlSyun6VF6NEz3jQOpDU4F/tJ9cKrpzjDdTetpXZJGwwlU9//3Dwzn1YEB2AyI6QzTDiJOd@DZPTh4Bfg6kPYl/KnpdHoImRymr@E/raHYpsPw6PmhEb2F6@Pdx4u7i8A5C35UQDtISuFkOpzMh8NqPZc3PwXj4cbFebheDqXsi4sU15tYZqVMpyHe3TUaW/ubjUYKOWltKfYslngGV6UaWxOPp6Fq@elFKYE1yDkw2Qil1p5eVLMJdOdjUE0Z8FtLxb7xGqOEZ3XxIgCm4NkZ/s5urm@4ixzkukD/swYPhl@KvOiVvOC6vknNRzDhYKCE/iP9tw/@6/p/dcoi5/UoY5Hbu7UIXVH8i0Zv727vxL0ajUTES2QN/tAD3jHK7V0VnQR0C67zSLQevbvjfnCPRNc4wiqmsValyGNAaLMhnupFuMwYGE0RMd92cTFMp6PlJvh4I@/yF5q6iZZpUctSE6fbwFCQlqMEklspl1eEe7VQLheEW8rny@VlDyoNL8IJQIott8rI6eWQGcU8cP6PpHG8hc6cDUfaSgc/PvDUNMHok4rpL188r0ajrVqNBvpnv3y5gKYUxjUtlWIOfNKFL1@gIYajYBDuG2I2tQjmnZTKjNH3ZFt2HCsCJn/8IoxLAu2LcBTDM@k0AmN8lltby69Uq/kVcOcL0Wg5uMQXxES6saIUvVtKBXkxwFQLh0SQVFiNku9dGMNZaI09rQKH23ix27sQUZut5KKR5kiJeh5Ssch92Eo@UogVxV9lMcpS1WUm/s7Ps7GV5dXlZ/X6uKNGMVG@lSvSXeVWLuHwwV25JQ58xQW48pMn2SKQpZAuXwQajc3aSa2BX87AqWkQwww9SeAEcNrRtMLnNNaTK9bPsSD1i3C4VH7G67WQY6FwWcAlwiC6WKFI5Q2BQal2cOX9ELAi3kCoJC1nsoup3PC7/FYaDKFlvM7PzwuZQmwZ5NpysViv18l3jWKc94edOh36VUmcS/lcPYHqy@WwsxwymbSaDS0HTFpgtJpmbZyjtXDcbBE8oUpZE6fTbUXT3PN1bwxLa9@obWUxEDrcq21sncQza4Ays13biGeOT9dDEr7mxu8UnMX3o63a5sEpRDjc26odbz3ffbN1egj@eBonXP1DWRkoDeVmMLjB94ZC14Zqy5eXsmk2TLiGnR9@@bs//PJ/@OHPf/7Dn//uD3/@x7/6xR//Lvz@En4/58@f/7tiDu@/@sW/@Lc//Nmfg@d/hN9/gN9f/@oX/@on/EfvfwO//8vn9zfi54PjvwDg@r1f/eIP/@JXv/j9P4Hfvxa/P5n9/cFfz//98U/v/2G8P/y3D8P8/N/D73/juFzYn/8Z98PnDPyfcbjf/5Mf/uh/5///Sfyh889/@KO/wZt4@d2f//DTP/zhp7/zw09/9sNP/ymwzT/81S/x/w//6h/@wy/x/3/9N//wV//TP/ze/0KOP@WO/@df/zt@//vf@d2//@m//Pvf@cU999998P6LR/j/4h/B5/H5fAyex5TrW31@8aPy85tQY5wK8AAw0j//4V/9M@ClP@Jv/yO8wb8X9DPvxQuJkZ2ZiI09f8bYlxToculnXzxQQPk/oy94sy@T2Mg37fr@6hf/8i/QewL2n/kxpKVZ2CUE9lL7GTYGL2N@2J9hc/rhlz/54S/@6Q@//NMffvl7KGETK8V4LZ6QvjJcBYC5R8AhYP4xcAAoreHM/SJbDGTAsbiGwysBKfbxI5B1EVxgFiwHcll4C9XrVbwuzlPVi9RFlV91eE@mquiTTF2kMDyZAquiwb4DOwx/z54ts@8SCf4c@wWkKqGGPMago5HAaFvmoyUxtFnhNwysFOENx09i0D/GeFAMgtZjrFKpxALDCoQRKLxinCGrFtAaRsOoAngxEo8TbxRA5WbDdcICMSuxI9ZYrgx5xBh6VAkDwwyh11FQygRjhcomJFgZbjLEhchjgY/w/FipFirDKqL7nrIAOGLrkCRAVTB3w@r38F4hnAAfGG5@D1kpVGKxagF8KlRUSi3eoDSlHBWOyh5jVG70BysdHk@fMfZdUCoEuYEKNcMENN5jY@inNE7zFMIvYsuiOPTvOum3jPGh2odEH@7Hw5@iN8UXAIA3kcBFY/CDagSAZxA85KhilCw8YhwDUC4mhh08D9JOYoEY1W@MXiB9yMPjrrWq7wXRYXGWlpbAtVYNZoMHYOcw66pkO7KFcyqkwJVYMF8MojeuwVGWDskSWt5chrsE/1uLtI6Wk2M5sBRGZSXM3DQSsayxYoQo927RqCzLlPMYwQVCY3@ufNPEGGjNKywaiNCR@FEyqBXThOcru7tuDEFBjgeDcSnPh76jwt5@Z5RKle@lldUAPOl9gKfxi3PhoRrwC21JbKxI0OptYo0aLjhBocoHqlUxucekQPV46wQinBwwKZNOMtCqb1dWMyu5lVwmm8/nVjPSSr64ks8VsiD08ulcJiMVV1aKheLqHWXpGQiOeGm5mVur/pOZ67/7J/Ou@b54Bapv2TDJEneB6jCRSGUoxxUpt1oeVSAf5BWokqrI7YfRbQLXdAYuaA3ZLS5XgmwFbhPIpgtwscBCgC2AF1yAFqc1mJhr3z0oi0lH/M4Jn3gMSjlghGjgAhiBYwuYk1cAq@0JyJonEnfm8mNnGp0nuO1uH1KAStDZHi7vdAx2YvBlhOtKK7AmNoxVAwGaozkHktYD@BmB83pgLeWFzse00eMf/9uwDFC/fzzMuqxf8aBNlW8V8oJ2ZDzLy@6rTu8eiFOzj9tvFOsfDcNWvwkZxLFYDrAON0szjHkAq@z08J5SvvK28eJkJ@3jBfCj3ec7J77nyVZtYyeQZ@sH@5tTj5wAyrG9re0T73WVh7pRcx6Kd1t7e9Ov4oEm1CLLrcbjIB3hhs84XfRMLn1wQaTkAwOx0DWl1tgS2sg5aO/4LdmLSlUedvQBcDcYgA2FNSrr51I5VK8WQMisrOZW8@niKrTW/UF/gJRgp4MC6w6c0e4BS5cZir3AK1ztVpT4rg3VDuyAzdXHjwLggRJOwFLaYH/d6LQhpYmf9hqY7F5PeKAXOi2124Nc3BguQKApywx@33pBfMV/OQ97ODwN8psJ0eaA4/ye2mHpQJLG5jLFQq5QzGYK8UKxsJID0zQXlzJxabWwWkzHpbRUkPKFXFGKF1aK2RUQihCaK64GQiA81E4qBTJfCgbpqeotPLh3DU9ANpK9aiDERzago8VvVoZkzwOqJZgtXKQhXjCAK3mZWlkM4ldh0/jNVUAosxYLbW9vpLe3g8F1fMGhyI10MNjGl1whnV5dDwYVCtkAuZ0JBg0eB4IAzOEv6fT6RjA44Ahw73Ew2MOXrTzqrMGgii8bte1tTOcSXzIYH8CueAh/0dyXVQDT8SWbJaU3GPzkoQO4Gk9ohXK6hS@YJoZs85ANCAsGn7v5SacBwxGH4xh23LLWasHgLn@p1TDkBRU8x7P6El9qdAWDFrwADwaDXXB0LUXRg8EmOJETg8EWuFojGfzwkGTcpqo7cjA44gRCEgWDQ4KWW1dB0KaEPyazs7Mj95y20uXXyOLPFmQNQtThYGu7@fx5s9ttWqPa1vMjDHnxYke@HA2sZrcpojUbcBkQB0Ku@qPpC/K422jI2tyQlxCiT4U0Rg0F89aQP0GexNXFRPqNFxDyAkLmTfxwbHD1AbSJ13ofnutyk0Lci0LoOWw2g2XkUWdkKjgChE2GVkSV/T59uWUZZXSB@s0Ww5FwfHQu1eOfyxTC@oxForfp8h2CdCL0wReUjqDr3I7Oh5V0HZRuqYyDU5HF/tMgiLxgaVF@GhmiOx8sgdq9EoyW8GM5RifMwgnp6aAQzK8GS8vwDD4NZsE5jKTDacbgFj1frT8NriKS4NOniSDkBV4BRIaIwdUiIiyuggpQvgN6ONAlNQeO0mhEIjeKfBWN8jLxD2yxs7Oz6C1fBaZSGZ1yJzKMDys8N0yNlj9D5qcxtXFn7qDlGBbH1wUKfH6aLlEhIfkCJc9SqegaSiSUIfD8SKPrSVZK8G/LSIV8NImLxhtGp0FfeWAf3SH4s7MZF7@Y3wPVwzPc/UE7P91lQqQZ26XACeqQ9PFKhjv@m/i9J9psC8YJP3qEvs6kgEZZDASqQqnCzbvJ7YGOpUviF6icsgg5UYZOckfBxTwt12@D77FMbg3xI42qobsBxyPQDPrJ3YPkqW7LHaV8mzhL3NGGX9ytiZuV1TaTK1Vwye0IJcTk6A3luVGtVhqVvtI3nRHYIKQGV7240AOydcYhcd@Hu/QdekwoSrqs49Ec1IEuDUPDQLWN25HXK@u3g1IJYO/KSkWxLMMKhoLlzlO9MqAMHioW7tLYPVjqMAW3Q7R6Hy@2EG4DqHZ7l6haTC93K@eY7he8rSWCwXoicf6lDspuJV0eheSKPWjS4Q8s3QRtPF8egp@0ulLWoKh8q8sSLXiTyz3WrDQ/DMtXFeivIM0My6@UrYo5sJTyJ8i8Bb065XwTom42IEY7Ao9GlEIIe@U8ky7GMxJ0ZdDFgQf8VuF9BX4S/DL1xcWIFpEUKe4YWzqQLV0qIfWA7PQKTzkayyxrkbbB5LUE1QI0qDLmAppxj5lqvBeBWEeKrHHwaOwq9ulpJhZpJzcb0afZBMsWo2V/5USi5chitGIrn8qdSuQDKOOk8H/RcPx5sVFJc9V/yR70z9OLeSl@m2gk7jTZdpak1UzpfLB0npAg6@kv3bXg@2qwDkS@C4CV4B8ehz68DH5u2@K9/rjfHvuZZVDJNAWqRCpmygIkYIoWHgmyCH5VjS/9ioTDq5lwOBouA9QieJOgiN5Suw6DtAk/ARkDegMImWIGwi3FGYCqCtJvJgfcvMlLgdBdoK3aJlspBkK3gbvbu7Wqqwm@ZKORHEu4r08Y68bA0E3RdF6yEWKL5Eokq89YrVLrHtXKArS2QeZoKsAu@IbCRGrxWycNY2vVD/x5gVPGkEyAE4dm1lNrsWrqIhAMYjMRsz2RQi7KzeDvQ3SuKdu47aCogIZfeoW0kkvH9LmB83r0@31Vuy1kE1WykIAp7u5CMSgbrhmppohSrQNaqhEI6YZw4gSAA3IGpGguF0RrWWHmcfHD6ofCh1enB6cH2@xZulQoFTgZLrgBG5fCUhis42egvqlHW4GQ@cXISd/rL8qhkhnOroSzEwr4RUXspY8gE0TOcXoMfvVzsIPrUXBVKtJTabWk2mL2KlKyB6ZiRZ9K@Uwpk5aiIfsON/pmVkP0lPKroXqIo1xZjYKb5l0yUqiaEt7SKsZK8Dfg3lzILn4JZdKFQKjw6uMXxtzvQKsZcqVSIrNLd2t38F@9Owf7/46GAe7oH28puN1xAPrHCO4LPcbXBNwYZhxe/z6xxv/X6LZxwHMezENFhD5C27ftD40PjVAgVAyDARNmmZzI41CY1qiEL@v0p9jL@Pdh7LFs2/ay9wavy1BmlqtKDNT2VOoi@joDCnuxmC/kQ4Ffz16p5YUAW16osTA/Ooz3dnhwqLeZLDzxZTYcu1leSGweH2y83DrB7k7R8cu6bONgP4lB@PHX8W7AlqbIljYSX38dIRT2kicbh8wAa2vzkOKc0T5Q8qUhGpHK0m67JD6RFL9mUjKLc5K5VHolJeWYVCilV0uZPJNBDtl47oNwLWFURsXaMMwRN7MiG1GKvFBDGAzbU8HotZUSe364RzHoSIjlhc2tVwfsYH/vXdL15f4nO7vH7Phg@@SsdrQF5Xi1dcyCtWO2exxkZ7snOwenJ6y2/45B8FFt/2R36xgRpAIow1Dt4wTzbB62Zo/sFOqENhk@E9620bpSnEl/2TLlFJ6EO@mt43dxFPyaxKT/QFfBqvLbVMe1Ba5gMUQvt9tWADegqi22gAbVwjL037j/tZe2V1lu8PZz2sotstbKfniVtdL7enZtlWlp8ce0lX72iC0uLl7oQa8D8BfDM@n8Xrh1AfzGedp9v7UQya@wZTDkMivRccj@weFC2n1bODs6WZC8sKPNhYz3sru9kPVetuBtxXvbPttcyHlv67WXC/lxtP2NhVXvbXNrY6HgvQGTLhTHOPc3F6R0wCXWNahYC/Ttv8j27t4WWwagaHkiFAfO0DHlDYSIgFrETwMhG3Z5@aZnxMkiaI6moNvK16Bd8AmoBVRvzpGu9ThbNky4gcoHwBAt4KnostVtxQVWPDUKepbAbWABC7SABQL4BdyHjnBsscIyUQbBCx2@PCLCTxGMs@CpTbtNv7PZGuraVWCGOB1DRbuOIYYiPgIaWLgTKCMdGlzs0FJqAgW7hwWtYDSKWxX3T/f2eGIm6ZORIEEyrlzOwWmYgA2KCHcsOvjyyuHVQnWBtFoQWgV@qDRwN1GbgenaRFJAORcWWoBgkrrXshZnqFXFce4d8eIL3wIBwBAM7jS4@B7NSKSFZe0qTosyFEVibh1s8xLi7H2FTdZylGGiRCkK5psrvnxh7tuFM/lqTb7qYY5bIOfZ4vh4TisIG0W/BXdzLEHQQQAUcwE5JhaD2FAcCvOVawGIDj9@boCbyyoklA6zJ08oH2vwVgxTEhgvRimyBIIgAkEwIh8i87K2SNmNLqSWcV0NrbKhk06xH@EH0zZH3pknIFmnMzpVq14r9KpzQQcTszwlkEVQp411De5spgHvKB6Bk@OsCc0kztxAKY@BaIvFmRJnHfCekqkNVQfOVayxTHRZARoj1f7@Jq8hfsAP@XMPKjHIvRJVGAiLJ9h8idEXFpoWGNplFwrkIUEB3yLTRJAQHO7heEebFG2ZtxdkS4z9mJi72yWXj3hsYAfBaURWPJOB84ooLnlWx0Az@AUybL8VQM9ZkiOLxQSEx2UCbGsSLpHgcHcuX36lEFvTpVj85lKgWL63FFuPLMZvVgro1sYsAqUAER8BvDGApttkbWbmoYC@kFBQaX4cCuhAx7wEbXwCwSPiQ5c7jp/49vjQSZemmzK0W6hBLhV4lMnX1uRre/IVmy/4yAxsgswK@8Ka6JLy4MK9@awAjjaXlZMRO5OvNFRTYYobp@NJYJ4C8ByKSg6GDDgrjFGCJG38iIbcx085VVhtu7G7v3UyGYr4knZDZLznGLpGaUQnwUSGMNyO4EvUy1Gkg0Tg@mbkkKcRJ3o2jk@Otmqv4pC/KFsbt4BpHQBuoiVMlODOTQF8daUF/XE7ziLHNbYcZU8wZ3EmBgvw5dFJaIatAKp7U2wPzAwlleYg3vtkSwphiwzMSSoYYZEo@3JxAV1qepVJffNLtp/VV7NtNsquorLL8Xg6iJDyroDZ502TKxsI2eYnJpbmJnaZTrMVK8scpQca9zBtzeKnct1h30bdoruD2DTIKLPLDDdso2wR561Avzip2jysRVLfiHyAvtiMwQ@7cxoki5F@juxJoa6CxfPSVr41L1/TaCfzkuB5WaNEZ/PwazEkCuZSYGqXOB1bY5iOKeNGahF4QAOph@hlBQJ8nMV3elnEwM/nONESnTqDMqXRwKNSG42IrWgdYFZjYLWgy0d12RZgeGFokgdSQ0LHZKAgD@pPkwFtFTc@40GU0OtMIcRzRcAbz0qMUIqBgJcz21FMypUvGzhOht@V9icIBvbEO1Qrbkj05ThaElrxtoztwUV2PnHgFMcxsHvxOd4gnmd9PTadE@axzZwwPFdwXhR3o/ycsMtBf14OQDDcEyK2us4J0Y2DeRH4eU3jgPq5j4DnfgLX65Ho/KqHdjVZ474Dt4j@J9ZAEadH7R74WBCUS8GBvroObSrAtC0VP0owjcjbbA8xI8Oob9@/x1bRMSfJdktVp9G7mAQi2rhK5@6zYanVA6zfSZlCNO5D6MPY5gez3oeT@ZBCDucgCbFj4n13BNT2UCMLTuMdx0/isRV6G8y7cQTDfAAeQ8ewWPku8AKeOOaFeMw8p8mN0ZVmGYf8cdAdq1@aOJvtPmi3EFLUT9DfNPnEtyaf8KWPbfJHJV1h55P5qMd87yXwGJfRbeA/KiE315OpRb@pxH6uUZSre9gXz9DxJcPPzphM1kMjJJDHU25RCD16PFJIIC4/om@QL1R9Ymf/vNjj/me5whKSF4dLvHFroMF1X@YDeOpHo4HH5TYadE5io4EjS41GkKdAHS92eP5OVzQ2HpYELbVhUGgkmJCD8WAiUTve2N1NqHowzs95rwRtx7CUBh53Fozj7HAlSAKrgTA9RTMrQbFeT7YZxQ7en0bNlwYU8OuJEBBPZVenRMbn4H49uZa/SMYjimRMJTY@m/MRqR1RangMwUMpWfyQOzehDTqHDQ@2sxQVBQ0/wV58lB0PLJk4JwOH9EUWeLo2jfTZeDoJzxI9Gugn6hqP@dhTyaqm0b6ge25PcOaYHdHacagHEYw5lXNf8JC@c8XoDLe2IvQsGh5KBsfnd4qMJUVJffzuKmj82JNxhzZ5lo/Ib9wdm7RxGHMqq2PBYphY@PMgHvUDFXBomHD3jvsBt3fgD7jxyB/0ckUduPG8H4zREQ5x9A@46PAfeAJ7B8dnjfblodof4MCN/0AJocmNs4VdPpaEen0KnJR@nKIIkdTw0OaIwBuNBUtBKLpNBw1NHzaE8PPOG4rWA7NClk7Hxmz6VId5SOeeYBSN/xYqyaeIoWi2RW4gbjzIglwJobhSqQ7Gp493XBGD6vOUn8FHPRERlCTuxR/3V77ziioT5gVSBIwHnplxBD7K5P@eJCn30ZKngoxrzA/FFbc5@cYFt/dm3I/BVdSigQcsqf/f2En@Kvmv1FT6/94omjF9/pFNmQdMmG@2Vn6LZsF/U@j/m0L/IxT635o2f49KPo1ytsVPqetfVcO/Xf0imTeCbsPqXuPQW@bH6GG/JUVg9Zv0ADfX59JDusDX@2cXTcbfrf/IXjrw69RJO3@2bdRqtZO@ZB09r3VrvdoRHg21nt6LnV2urG/erD9fb9c2N7svuhv7yutCbWXPfPm28O555/MnBbT3nYMX7z9rZqsXeHtk3pwphzdZpWDXBoNPuzsjZ2f9tL9xnHu3epPe0nKddeXTpmZvvjp5@/Lkee44dvPpxeGLz/103z7spOViP7vzKv9mY3SmB3LX6ml7e0896B@3t04z/b1N9d12bCO9d1x8LaX3tm7eZzduYrl0atd8efD86PSyufVeO9rde9fe@GTI@U9XN@Zuql3sbFwevQkcZF9LO58ODrpbmeLzndTNZsdspzM7mpW7fHt0uH76bqf3Ut7qb@dOi28vR4f53uvX185@rLtylh@8sldieu3168xL/fn19dZRoCkbJ1ZWOTNeS@bNzaFR7K8qL/d3uv3XlqSnDnJvYsf9k5vNrXXt0@owe/ru7PXNyvG7wavXL94fpNXj4@aWnDeb7czx5clKoNXP7sauT7dOC/Lz9tnr/vXuTu7dZupVT9mvtQ@1q@fdnffG8eHebi1rD3Rpb@Nae/e8d/nqanNjVzMOrzS9tpLKaSftdwcHgdMXanNT2Xlrv6hd9t6lcutXK@9ibfP5yeXn3tWL9ePTg0JmeDhKGxv2UXOnM9w8ymcKqZb26ehzx3glnb6O5a8vX2TUd7XPTiD7eZQr7mnvlL7@Itbqvh9@0lKxU0naeL/7@d27451rq1nTTz@92T66tF619QP7IH304uWrpnZVcC7N9/rxsdRKP1euXsXScmB4umNDHSkncm71pL/32hxuGp@Odt/b@c@x67OrrLJ5dfSm9uko3bzRzbe6taf2N9LtA7n2xnC2BsPnreL16dWOtvfpwH4XeLUl5XLbRsde77xZKb5NPY91rp6/XZeOh@l9/aizkrf237w@U9Wt3tvTz0et3PYbs9B39O7rz6f9rdjW3rD3WSmkm9rxuys9cJo7PjrM3Ogv1b6zvXP0Ku8cpPfeHLZ3RlLttSLd6Ksbo9zm0MpnzzbfWu@udnQz9U79NDhMK9ex9jvTWXmtNjutN2qr/zJw/KJ3un/45mY3l7ee93V1/bCQ3t/b2djvtldejnZfDbb2mpft57tvlbfmSf4qs7V@lt98e5x1Tq5eOsXWdT97WIidaH2nexoLvBj0BquHZ9anN8P3K7V@U8keae@M0arU33hhZoZvalsHn7tXh6axL21nRqnTPeNKS38@ufm8Y@dro1hheOr0DedEGuak14HszWfTeWG@eH18sP7i4P0LeUVVz@TL4zftdPa0kFJ7VnY3n38ubW13@p/6RUX6vPkqK2f7vZi9d5Vqb7RP35xdaZf9l/3LVqBQtFvru@8HsrHVzEjpd@udrZyyt753Iimn3ZfHK5v76cO37cPTT8OT9sbbwembAzW9dfmiuNddeXv0pvhy9f2JfSKfGW9fWvuBYSFr2FK@mLvJHhcLBz3rOHt2WXTev7zMr2tnTenFbqavbKvW28KocGV@7t10b46VdLP7fPOTfNTZAkl6epiWc4Or/eFxIPvmpH@9aq7H3l21Xr7VJa1wpq6mTj5dFq96vZc3m62Vs9rnT3Lu@aVSPN5ONbXt3PPY0cbrw8vu5tnnwko7vb73Rn473Oo57wKvd9TNy@LZ1cFwJL3ePh71a2ldy10fn@WuT4z147Od40LvVdPqNHcueyAb@qPTy5vB9Y6y2hveFF72Lt/I6b23hQ3dXjlMB14ou/320cnLt7VYJ6MUneuDd/vmWeFsmHtVMM6KxkFBfVnrPB@@PuhspVdN9exkeLrVS61vqP0CyJRD7dTaOHi98/7shZkOZPT8@ucNI7f6KXY9fJc/Sx3G9gbvWieZ/pll7bxVre2314dvXx7XdmO7zdHzwyv54N1W7nh/Y8N@EdtW88poJ3tj1zayWscI2P314f7QMovZ91d7XegJjHax/fwke6bbtVrnZrdwvFWrPbebuy/k4fB5ZxX6CLy2zt4YlcCv@bF/AX7iH3/I/GyRQN/uNo0hyEu@ATBAu7oCtKsrwPdx0RJpvvz416nlwIl/PwN9DZkP8AyaoKyxtoHKQ5Ltemfz4qc54qxvQHQVXS3DpCeiFfs22mjwaXCn8SrcYkjfclSGpmao@NUj/AID2qTW@LNrycCBzvojtDcdpc93Waj44SJxlC59tIF/H4qO8gwstFrM/eJlkg6K9b5/@REUCFPvJuhk4C5LJFodTe7a4NDa5PoYOPZOrscUNFXGwQ9MQtpryFI6J5am0lfqMHMn@L2l/edMM/gnIVyLQwZlYkRnq@AgFZ2vouBX8Wz1WtFG9I0PpZ0M8BWfj1oF6ffD5d2TfnSc6dTaUFA3FGtqAajJI7ozranlZ3jszbPllJhiRWWoIVtN1cFvLjf4fokGT9Fd82ZOrj2knb9igpYrRqjZ0EHAcbF9aYhvU7GQYrTMvEX7TjgCVA1RRXVXGy4vm4SS1l0x/uLDvGzej1vtd39bqCdwt1VlAq8BtBoArWhCembO/jubFjl6QOUAn6zfert70hAfguFLDCc2Rd2z4tJH5bL7ZpZ5CXz5FzmfXZaJKwwg@zjsyM/RhqJeG5yXg7TuEZdHQm2jhT1ebZkErqGVBojNpNUo5yt1voIwTUv3XIJ7cZ5wTnjiy9WTMUEXxIIKjwceGY8v0OQgs@VFxB1LUQiAVnO6W0OmFvv9lnnvnppparJ@ha4yXyoL9oLV8lUWfeLCVw4cyvLKItZPko2A5Yao3jLYcUaDllctBCAWxLrVfKpjc6b19hiH17CXNI6PYRqe1aVpRisyDl52l9zwskXdlDj8VFIHOJLYwZW1hjXiCeHwTKRcBhBcp0MyQdHd1aq@UlfG1EB0tKjHlwvg27LrhccMKON8xtnDueVJLRI70Aqg@Vnli4EQ6tzLVp0ndb8sBHpH/YWZiDomjruECJypZeYYJhChIzgOujHiEb46dYYqfKWXx0WM0@k8XYd/9tT/UuILd7FBKTjsiSIkis0YLfSpzHmZRtCq13QwqTHrUUXhCm6sQpV4kalg4aM/U2OxiXryIT9XkW4SixG1I3NCQQx5JRKkF7QnGFoTB7XBl@KyDl/BxWkdmCLRGiT05YvXYODV48ZDdxsmsIT3hXdkcM6ZvC0Lgpbdd7cRem4KGRPFk6p3s2vpaQcqGODGjakOFS0CArOBH7gxGXiJJUumyR0E4S1fAm@sbMq7kFeLixGIdU5wqUKdPWERaW0tspqIkNd3hWjUa4wiesYX3RcZhHS1yiKZ5UjWjbyCkQFldhLBynwEGY5gZTkiuQgyAoGUAwxcxSAk37EC59pJxAUfYg9vfRIGP5MzJ/XlTEyqr60VcI2nz3MqcmZ@1pezsQxE5qgXYpMhHC0P8PnXJ0sEyLMZXz/iQ7ESywIKnnRsMmCc6lSAl6g/zZX63M7pt6a8uPs03M6HouPXOhXrvIDlRU7li9JNBm7TsYQnfjHNpO@mjf04Sy8jm4OOQE0SUuspuGkqzr@bJzotoF95qlf0bY4gCBQDRAQXjxpnlw/1dc1v7@wQuEMDfLzMcSbFWQHMEJAoIDEKEBlECNFA7TZafdODg664EOUrvnkHRons44wz7h@AekK1302JxBgnH85wAz7x3TLqQzh9IxChsbe7jo83W0e4YnZ3/zlU4QKWI87Gd7eYixyjV8QNWeffUlEdFbIAso0bNKKsvKom00dPN32BzUUu4Kex84hUOoRgPLLQDokvVKehGgIbJ6XLR4pDdKRPe3kAhWgZ7Ax2ozBZQ3KM@CeJC/wLYLTpjWITqcDhRRQZRAohzU6OavvH2wdHr4hyh43a3uFODTGDgdmSrTajb9RgA9F1ReOdqkfPAHa/Xfx4OJZJbrofVOGfVUdY/rFDTjwAbFBIg3ync4Tl5Uw/A8@950UgieJBg1LRaCvmHNy4dtUDE4Wx5yDktchzLbpCkad5PSF1eLM9oStHqyjpiJaGYuthBxibvtkj61yepFx862Bl0gcPqeWiHtUlfrH4F96yGfrsM/KRPTBxdlhpB/3kl1stxaZzD8bUB5SK1qFEhGTxEQp85pd@LD/43hSv7xU46KuX1OmmPb13rOZOKougPXLa/Sgd16cgcSyujnTrqpWkFomU@VeoJ1RHdVJlvC8xntolT@0SUuMCl11OK2Rq/fxyQhGbRx7VJc8l141dzYyrJ95Scqq5DjR6u4fHEdFYCJc6VGFYTXQUhzGakHVP3Cp74rbicUucr9w9rJQJwk5qZKLDGfefwmBut4FskZmxDdq5QtbXwML65y@6coMv1FPyjU6uiUHwxCkNUKddOFd84h6qezkDMYE0pN0y5yK5OnUqHr6IQMgSbn6iPl2DdmGKUQFVB2kx3pwmykqqpGELQ9HniWJV9MJW223kBDnuzKz29IYuBEJfvuFwvCuBb@PjCRXQSV/MrBBq5JCxzkoBXFdNJCBClI9rkE4D4hbLQNlTnfnFKMwWQxTO1clUvgMGRZ1wS1wUIOgXsHvA1028PLfcvnK4m@EwctRXsHRZ7KBwd/SeHrKslM36tv8enO2zfH68OxjPNGMrmfR4yzGebsbyxcCPGicbjydwfsSGIyoU2Qp5Bk130AUVTYNGzB9tFbt@zBs3i4f8MSp7ytUyt2BtIY5F12Cz/sDGIUr85jzO1zpMGkrJwAIIRRoDFh/zdDtvAOwOZEvWHYXvsURBLmZ2MUGKiDqsYkG5mtAycNkYSnz8FD10C5bCB4DBp220aJEk4qB4UNODPq1GiqPCcK1YeAyA6oiN/gskcwQ7cNFQ5UzgerrCoeryBiehEAnUonGQhZORumWkHh96Ea4MqSsne2nK5cmeRF2a@11gzACRV7AK0Zi7AwuCwDPdDNnjy@LjaG6T9IDHon/e0OBsJ8ONU9cOF2h4HzNr@av1OYMxxF0tfx80FIuYCBWVqR5198CRBHC3QLXccQgORI9hnbonwsWtUaQg2C9tlY@FM5IRpEVQL0VdioVch6t0xCl3FLzgfRmd@LkCrS8qVgaMxIY5b3ukgECWj3IIsTdyGgLbJ4cY@nFALnhDXU6N1x8MEYe33w3FN3GIa4WjOyrsAkTA7VpSu3j@@Z60@aUQbZQS5VvSpnNKQVFfW54PxosswLB0PjDIFMkjt1Au2OnheN@bC0i5pwGphzI/kdpjMy@SmwGaoMQjs@4R4k6M1c1DCpH7xrXCJ6nEshqhZvrqhytJUImCEYhnqd2LoQpBA1cq8Nw1fTG4zuzGcSUJhYhNv7MiR0B5juWMux3YFejeMOd4X@@8gnJOdovqFpNqkL5OrqkmdY2TZRXNwl/WhDRb2FVfYd1dxhOFFZHccs6e76CDo6MZN/z8BexQgmLncvC7dpx918bJEOHj76NcasyTf5N7nX0N8kNl3CK98nl5pU2z3gtvq2LuEEW7n98xHuJNu40cP09NXYCE4IZedhfX81gLC0KdAaVnIl4mKoadPXZ2UXQ6IK9pqT6eYruXcTGNOYawVNj3HA91QZ8VawLYBftCch4zEPVgOyqU1Afr4yIhmScaqcsdGBCLif6sMjEaPN5AfS8j@rEI2enbovxgfJIps7kYYRjvJufjcKOI7n7c/sv@jIzuzQiSg@aIRF/nzRnxIxHuftOZ0bHuZgrNDfQuMwO3T0IRE/pbLu3qARFzrC941gG3B/y6gVC0XWUQB7ZAgQfbmG@NjjNI/V748Qkjn/gEH27Ng5h0Aog/Gh014RdIPIcZn1lk@oyY2WxS7RBFTV4nk/mmiqSBEA87L8YT8xyRpTIJnAbkzpg0U6oJdIw2OdNoXJkf/kGqLJ4/Tnaq//QPrPhlLDxOWY7tLBM3B7urHQiF2jc1he/ckfYatYNd72gr1nMcs5RKKbaBXnbSsLqpG/VKTXHAwLE4tiqhDLCd4yFVPKSxdQpdGR445STZscIXK6Dei2rZRzInlUH0I0bCE7B0AO50QOPVWwp@nMW5wfUDAoGd9GcWgmUb9HBDZyPDaI5zL4udOTwDccq7DZnvAmEGzSRkINWSHVsZKSmMmGpqcOvLeJZ0CkzyFJYwdaArexD7GJqEkryUr@XApi9jtHN6KlU6hi6QwLEjCnHwc@a0egTHEBxcF8maBtSNtz5VGAl0lKShayOm4xEAXcB0jdAgVSAp5LwbKCatuBWTOrTkQSE7YiVdzJOwt0UPR/Gw/04mISwXDfBP8ZZwf4dtILtYCq1NpegTa1qm1mTwhjm5iILb@ZN@LTyc6@vrNLwlHqmUL66hP2bdx7w1HnT@F5D9vpUfqRQOj5qaPGLBG5lO8WYbK6vpfAltLbWrExtia8FDdHwauzI08YO2uDAA@3E3rqZcKxrLYjW@Ue0BAB47AyhSIGRacrcvu4CRbIlhMr4zusi@ntjRPw4yDG3Sp4P7JtjYosadaYxJY2y0g0v0KkhM4S36BSUKUgtuT3HJs2GYrASOttIcdKkzwH1ZbgzcHSXHmxhBjlYjzehTeJbgCVnHLC1DO8bGX/HOr8L1RIbKzqGZ15k7QREsB6gU0PQrPPdlNz72HAjmm9GBDpvPakCPsMwawhjlowQAjX1YhMPZfNyTJs9dkLaxe4CjNpQgX1zshmARTXHY471rSpaZb00JiAQ8bwoZk47ASqXckZFwDT9N7L6sh3kojRpFuHs8RMR7vWWPHO76hQ5ffbJGZ4IxOsSTyBktu6vqpTK7cwFxDQhqOLiyJBF2Vw6ghmnh3Mx4RQqQPuhaYQ@h9WUg@xVIqjhkM@yXfMXgC7zrfLRLqCDTwVLdncMC/0q67FKDf8ncq//xZNYTXpsLVPBF@i76LRPqdLDFJ2JolkRMME3kFTsvwSPEHRyX6OIjnB/IY5IbxGgiDZrGvQFVnlE@5grCAnXOBHUpcTZkXRx95@ZTnI3EK55UH@CHUafjo4pU9k6vVvRB/xaNkTiPMjDjCHzHFJD25QDehUVn8cS91g29BIl1FOQBEhTode7649DGbTrOpLsypdyiT5VxEQ96xCzvz12LdaEjvtI5mCL0X@fdROm7djDO08MpA3JIriNTj49T40T0cj0cGVeRYXwEooPhfqSqsDrQLQbn6XXkC6IzSsQ8jRAwOA7bkHHesYG0i7gnkLHGsAIGUmNUwTE8fv4XKry8WdABMghfYgCYSCAgWKjMVXYpnMgMom8Yi2E4GHWT4QOzhFa2G38mHGuP8PP4fvx340PyiA6NYbwxirrrUiBGY7RMJPCWp9zNFJey9xuUdya/U@WdoYdX3nvo4ZV3lp4/qrzeiPFbKgh0MfRAGwdN9qdgUQO058nHKZ4y9EyPe6jNd9OxByZ@cGgqNn1BYja2YZqGjWedz88BT3NOJijc5w9pPuVplMANBnKKDx9JhTQ0PfwqgB3gTdwyUF@MkBs/Ocn7L9AnNT62Lfpo8kDMRRrR914TU@@QQFR0JX4vVyR65cOkuEzl6gSobVe0vrjCfEmVvYxTQbkNxiiyV/oo468@HL6i0/JFyI0bBQkVZfOiDFDvwHjTUdBvfhRBdSEfJ2Mh1dncWG4lYmyxutLVhEjsBHe5lTTWuoO@uaYGSWdgV58@4dmx3njvMOYyOK8MGukNx9xeGkyx3Q6Ntm3whdjsUIxO4bYnUOGdnmUMuj2GB0WhDoiwfEl5x0DtHrVL0OrxO6MDPKum5C6Li4yL740fp9ipycDIp/3z2HJfHbINVPybIxxL5mMBEV83IVZYLSy4utPCeEh7gSS9B1znA318xGGcPNWZLwObyA@QhVc4EgfJHxE7zUnY7cQSkqeBBGXHwZP1UbNWeRGw@ONoJk7DjCOiBuCe8UXKyoIHOj@znI19uaXc@bO7B6wyL7fpuZmkbajTmWwqONSXfiBzfBRxeuwGsoOpY242lX@E@vNS5bPXYPd/hTUhUZcr4wSngJGLi6NB2cGteX08gBxP1uCcChY4oNw3LLQNR/G5mG9wPI5al3wDtheZyggXS4rs9MCevcaFRnNj04xbT4aqoq0DiAhyQKoVnzvD@TL8uBvGfkXmqBeZG8A2qXJ47izPhtHCWWY38iwlLKOlKG0bVVYZeYXyGcHtDaK5urOEbVXuooUIlroret3s0Hg0WYs9tcV3ZWwcYlYs5dNAtbixjblJQl3Suh9ghY2e0roiWPy40Rh7QtUTQDbdSRgdZn8ayBYOORgWi4XtgJDxvKc5EitxpvUoIaDKE8DEeZVZJcQHjOonHgU5xVbueB0O1bgyjxbr4Pc4wrb4GoYYM0La@sd@cNQkyUBeeQMy0D1rYoeuahMen/n9/7b3bMttJNc9C1/RGmoXA@JOURJFcLiURGqXiSQqFOW1C@JicRmQIwEYGDMQgaW4FeeeSipVjjd27NhO5WInlbwmKTuuSh7yvv4Hf4H/wDmX7p6ewQxJadfrSmrl8hLTffr07XT3Od3nUhL96QD3Yn9cwTzcCeOdNb@QsexcddiJYaybxkcMiDfWeK6BUaqhTDQGm45xeRLzTnMx@O0FaKwqA7jM0FrGMsZXDxoMZWzcYs87ZBQU3V9ANt2f20hvgYLpo67FxJUiBJapFUpUySJaOooXsY78UdnEzGCLiAEOwQqXnT/nC5o/gQzQCPce2GDQ/B1vGLttvKykpkvpE1Y69RIJWXYF9oHhdBC2R64/DQbzXzch5K5QzE7JO0PSnD6/Jj/j7DiKYSydVTEYgNit7pG6G@omoKAOm/fKg3XMsQ7kVoMTN/TlOSsG0gwmKKkQPfhMZB9g3gOZh4ej0glI5KDLBLzpQTWBkGy8Sqw2AFsnmYuNwgqVUwp27W44pU302EflCtQpneJ9EOp4TNBEjKYEN2zsCyL3x@6EKwNqm/tToc5noNfI1SdskJGvTQ8qlUcf4ce9GbuFdM8HCeBB3AYqVDk8co0ysP1CwwGc7o6g3ep467jyjgIPN37dwoicWANVC38Rt8c2cFGFb1wbv8LhnS9WibgT5WroVgAWm3FLxnr29lUp3xeUoJ/QfyKWWd11KVgmKKnbjy8JpFWxeC2nBFivQYoWtuegpsYGWljAugTQpnd41cG3FtbaoLsznMUTIBC3PekeQ5dgvjwkmHBC49TzejRsIMPhtbd2ZR4IQI9xjArMQI@mww66pOnTeGkzTXr3wEtyALEj1AWqOTK99GiH84pAz89Q1ZPuj3sFvba4KpJLUPgBQH2PhCeobBPdX8qBwe9Is0mPTt@Wn3gVsoLDgt9NmYhuSqQ/@oWslUPluV6LfCuNJMb6ORgL0eVZwiQML7xCQ8XpxJ@84JcjvHajnT9se3TvjW@BrLCMhdSNHj7yB1Eev2Soy7korAmtZzxYjtvhxZe8ippC2BQHbNDDhlPRAPMbXiNSWtbayDWmLdjCunwDVZVZqBnFZfnlkjd2TTzqzZXvENk2qGaabsmxdsylwHMtrzLZrm0y6EvuKkYbElJSBEKrluP1u7ySVHWUCQ1BceNZxqHGFx0F1pDmTmUz5QzFf26nGj5JK@5os6ZWI9OH4zB1RHVoJeGuoaq7rMwbWJ8sNvwUPdfRARzebNxox@Dr1IaYSf0usrSasYbXlYT8LbjHTWRJr1yZv87o0FhoNfHoTt4iapbLgOQOrQy4wrSRkPLUxtjnpZ9iqiKVPDncARzvAoMpSPMN@DQvw4OwoJ/r5QINwkoQEu0YJ32Zdx@g77R11x4EvnRlRgcrFwrovfD1XmLUCuTq5brrTPvYFHzphzKRgcqidcrVvt5ySDWXH/x5pAic9A6niIPXf8HQFlQO9dlqBaDIZEW@8MuCTXUnjuilGnVf3pFxD8RyS1Yr@6BcGGEn6MHbcGdDUtW7E/cI/ux72KJekEd@Sb98V3LbfJn4eG/30cHOfmt/5ys7@092qCQp8muD4um4SjdlwQk69x5JvPkg5hAn9/7Eg3McTxyKs4QS@JOuH4biPoi7LojjL9pQsj11c5lv7isPsvOeBu5kncsfMDNPxvekaRx4aCI0RVUl6N8JC@D8PGwHBSZ@OAPJIRVqvQ7QkwHHhcrhngmbOefg/okrqeNTlGiCkJYNeKT4/fAEOUApTcTfmOGkGfRgNbsVqWOroPHKIfKXoB0iIAMA@ah1O69QpHJzrcLAu8BzIhuJbeXYwyB736uJx1ztNlUrtrlfyEO2B/7oKCe9JxgtIM4NDq0SxkFfV0NMRkFQBeotoKdAHGnuEXeoivJBtV6pVT8/lwbRI/ZvyFvBG5jkv6Gd96Kdfmr8pDSzfRUDwOBxzhI2dLGwSakWdOnRmuIGdYmKVmRFb2ZOnm1NLtFf/w1bkGcYkMvWrX4xRuOfrz33pc2sP7OPhS/eDCeVgGNWOYp8U1VMzz4/g53/K1Yjr2cucpEVxZemE@mmEzKg2usYT@SX86R9jJzH7h5f2ONVk77@CZR2twxnlODJ1K4VU7TVEWziSvNRPBqpiXw5JfqYBn1MrfzXpg6f3dcUW4Cou@lqx6/Ra8M4ItbR2mtpwutAPReouJva@mex9qt6TbV9VGmfzJH3jC7ScM3J5sZVpGm3efVKxNTA2dKFdXyJ/KWGuTZvUU7ljcs4pYwuzw51Z8YlE@rvfCmYUloHeQtljCwOrxUPMSep1bRJlHC1RkwhXspRBYXrbHH8Emrr0QhGl6XkRMy8xJdttZdxbDAQFZ0NaHtQSM5RDGV0GZuFMj41ai6yKpMLbcEmRL/A/3@xttIkyAYeXxpZ/QaNrL60GvnSauRLq5HzrEaWrlanwaTa8UZVYM0GonwC3H9uCRbU9p54/707B@LgvR1x/@m93xZf23sq3r/zCFL2xOOndx/s3hPw/51HT3YEFdD/vuJOUOVewNRvu12XbudXarVVQZgXApSviiftoXjP77ovgXg2gvZw65g/KiM33ORSOy/dydzn56AxKrOE0mqC7or4rUndOKHFdQcoeYjviMqXJ7aRvHkGfLNEthcUDl0bcPPbHvEgpMdFz0raaAPgfUgFNG1@kiXdaXxaJ6alVxFy4PS/1x5BYAofPhF3Hm1jpM/t3YPdvUdPxP29ffh8/DV0syO2d9FtzN2nmEWAD/e2d@/v3rtDCdyAWkXg3RoZrJ/XhAqC06h0X/SnGB5sgFKh/Ip59V7K5Ua@sooIRH46itz39ICk8N2dnZ02yEW7fe3O/rtfQa7G/bqwLAxyaThUlxYI12poNAK1ySjaDXamjqxluc4b0nAurmF2I0d3QPS7JBTyAr0Te66w7uE1Ij5IU9xsZtgUaqjoKuBGVMoRrCMoAkM@X9oglJtQG90eqNrwYrWvPrDolnTMinLkkvLSGhBSDM64O@pyGF2VAHTPWt1UbThhALwQkgkMgHcwmBC2X7i7eEkibkiIaYiCPyTc5ITnw/H9E@Qa0cBVJtzlQCBrsk08bzSlGOCo7Y14HmNmTbw7UIwUKhIQPDrJGQzUlSupxAH/L9/Y8FUWIC3YBfuwspVQET27ATXA3n7c7oeBsJ0C3gaDCOKOPNbUOhq0Qdyje@EJGiy9RDUCqnbNwX@bylG9YjgpEKcSYTpzEW@HLrctD373suWg5N2FGlFvjzqNClMy/tOFDbi70IA3QQOIyuZ@gW6FxiExtoTG70tStgMfKBJEPvFxPKqR35t23VgBKevYz72PPirIQS5FRQwVH2qd1rDDUA/4EHKCPqjIzQUIMaQpeYyvUTyHdrwH0dvwEJUhJtjAD9XgytpM4UHVKDVxZKXIz2fU2mmTMdyFtRLFs26w3r7G2mcUPX8HbJZHzyQdFJO1NBegP2dUYkDPThN089IXqFg0D6klHNwhF@0dH4ug2vxgzdncvvus/PGHpcNq9Yi3hXaPHy9YKZGfWUgkh@WhdSdJG1CtNIk0F0w7WFrpM/JuiatcIQPG5dgD5nur1dB5fK26mD6ieFnxdEp89crhUmWyNyESwkgy0e5WEk1VZYnKHIqCRBDtndBY9KyrUkqEU@/XWxjXHmehASMywn2E1GvMsGqkX2N4u8YHPdhZcpJP4@nW@AsqFrmkKPpnm/NR/cC@6xQ3C1UFRYtJD6ettuiSwlwvyF6d4fTSebWAbvt8dLB/Xx7d2rmt4@PhtbBtn4vttdpWLmbj4mPJwHV5tB@fg5YPtzdCC30vZSPmQ3IRm6Z0TZyla0uK5i@o8cOFuaO1B2jw7MWIqhqpUdt0NEAPcTZfikPTqEDBRBMxRE8Otnf294W1g7ds61AW9r32qEv2pbgNIu6rytMR2yHTZlfRTJMOE6SZJ5Vyxual8WrPW8ypg5exVUgepCTHQ28WOmovSCYzaR3BJwuxEGh4zRuiGrl4607VHhQ0JeKzJmpCiWjSjA7mUru5xIcPO9mnTSYatxLzxsELb6yZGXcmnXXRVfVkbiJSjDAeB@0jfPlOn7/3mT9eV/Uwg@V@fUodRiX8LvrLF0@g4jG@FFfiM3jOtKgpJZ0VotIlNXZklhfnsD87QelY7GeSFza2dckcy6Yxf3zNiGRH/OkWvvPPZWZ3KO871RZPKRvmhBaiQ8@OH0HAZIIYLLZMqoDih2fyCKPR0Oekoxlyc61do9Y0VSspmpnE3cgGegs4@Bs3k9tDsirYbc@tqvz5VMWnRKwmI@7WYg0qEzDfvHHj@kW4k71QxcufFTefIcn9MxyOX7YNlME8IFUhoNzdRyWVHxHAOUPngBTYs9WCSRQEViflTIn1nQ4js33QlpMJ2uJBY/aeHpTwvihZa0HMEm1Lx84nkomdQBb6YCxh3VFeNQujf3Z@dXcpqNsF9V19/fp4sSEQ3oef/YrDZO77Y9wqgRGftNgrKojk6wFqxYVYgoMPak@/RgzMLRXHssnx5rb4hRttpLnGrdB/gXr9KnKmjG1m4TNUZdgen77CC65XdGXKeWgTIMt6JbH1nHVUOLLmVs8nJYK@DmW5xa2Mp8E2/7JlBt9cR/VBymMA4wHT0QOYfzsvQO5Zx1sFFWoyX@Q04E90UpmTgFZDlD10@jKno12CNx7MdXqV03suBp7TqRsSy0lbR7zMb0rIZITMvCWB6a7W689bNOw6@x3OBjZGJ70lGwOy5cDXqVc5FXWqVFJTlp1GSYecBJKUTlqSUHgweaFJS4HrvmjRJMtoc4AwXxIjb3BYkfpT79hSdixIE46QJxLKu6NejiaFYp5qVOpI2ELXspKEmlveYYUUKOUGhDJZNLG8kLa8qIAJDOlG6EsmKi5GDcD/ykbIpprEizU3t54jhU/coDt1xc4MZXwVG1FRJTkGWRI7j7bF3n2xv/d4J44aW9xCHoVKKYU9CsUsG0bdUUu2BBPuT8PjFieqz2Tuicu5CgV/a6CRPzGA@DOZqyogFIe4LMXpq94r0YTDe6wnxe4VDuWkqx7rPlS6/nQUnr6avaLpnQGnVwESeEecVfCS4J2FYZErUXLYihzoLQ7DQiJf2VJuFaJaKIVqmUnfHL60uE6s@cKZxJbT@ydMHaxM2qSjgJywTeJO4CPLsy7jW8JwdI@jgJv0lu0I2042DA@lSmUhuShu6cCNrhlxN17ZJSspZlVyO6qEKUzjqQQYRzSqrSB6vnjlvVKVRYcKHv1rSWlHjzb6bpbTaBwxtOxiMLVDI5tfJYw@93LxXwsLTs6giMcbla8bvCAwyHu0mztM4zEwou8FML05KDBeQAtwtApigLxMFgCp/CLGVnoro6WXUiS9xdF6XGxORi0RupQi6bVEjY5PRbTWE7PR9YE744Ak@KMFgqBxvqbOHJDNQsVZi1UkC0pSJHGmxXXa/KeQUofaphkC6PFQ/awfsumNyJvFzoWPj4jZAtl5Y0BwDyJ3Knismen1ZLp5JIlNo3gSwmhUAhhwJk6qi@eCPYnEkk7QUouXFRltyWjgyGvJoxG2nEMDlEgoA7QcB@VVE8ECKIIQF4cniwHKKzEOWkwHNYif4E2sibYaq1GDFtNBjfWxgLWchjUOWkyCLuxrtFHGx14ztMv2@ZNXyOBjTXRGVe7M7U5DPmmU0wpYQyEsD5PRktA978gL3xERo0W/KtAeJNrVNekRW6WBgH/jlmZ9qIBitc0myGojhLhbGLyUl1IxX0eZ7FvEmGvmMQbPIa7xfdwAbRKEOQ2CPTDJhigmQwo06hRTrJg5NFxqFooGGSMJSyydwucZcr/NpVMWdzjyu1WyCmcWN6sR20WhTypZykcbG2osKqHf8kTqv4ZsPOHwxyKOoxIlnfMvhmMa6lS84igN/C5fdpYQV0MJa01IRwGcHnYSOPA1ZbEvqiCgOby4HfigsogDm1AU53XKxKGEqkUcy5fGoQS2RRzly7eD5Km0vrx1aRwsCKbhqF4aB1Lg4phaS6eA4Iz/a6WRWmw80CxKprZLnThpaJzt2Fcn2Rclqgq0FyQMMfhZ4iutHZIxN2l9YIhBlxoPFDoWx8P2eCVtwlFMO3eNL5jrWLKwsF5YuKVUvoE1Vl5DXAvCHhwElf5Ar@@UxZ8Q0ROXJBIh3XugEFPpHk9ARMLZrEjpQzEghBPa32qhalarRTdDj/f33t2/87D16M5DFKKWeI/C6xvUliF1nVplBePZ821Li3SKHIGqFtiNHO3DRh61T6LZoVOEIsdiqaVTA@7MYgYKa3Lovqgyck/EfciioPULOBGyou9mYHpsaoPe1K3yS6sQQZonmOqVlNc2oSUEw3QiW0IwRnLOELa4/LMRa6g8Gz0LGbAjmmyTGRya7X2GhktGQSHKL5@FX3EnHdQlKWunpTyLqIKPshs5p0KVC3mDHmEwJvBX1aq4q5ziSvu19qCLLm@nfXJ8O/QG7WGn166Mj8e5fuBI9zR2vh@gk8scKlPtHuzsP2k9xjhdO/fIcgL/NSjvYPfhzt7TA8x5AlnXZfLO/v7efosU1PefPj5Aj6GJJMsElFgiMJkQA3q0996dBwYMf1uykWwQEoC8CX@kK5@S8MatGf13TmYeJVaFaFEQHjJTwaKUVhKhN3T9qQrehv4n1AFfQssTfJSBulRUY3JIY@P1p8yLfJ2eGVDUjsl0HBIoacDbiZEoxEswzDA4wgLkiygAvp206St8o4x5aMjnj@1EWTSQwWI5ad/VD2h14DJ5Mh91bYVOOvIsnbojgMTXpvw07JfX8mcF9Co5JqWhZOF8FU6OKjlHzaeXlCMotdJzRhAj89q1kVMG7wBFFiU0CZFlChXgF8SGKBa9wmnODBAls2BX5fhRp8KwoY/DyPg1V4w5YremrOcL9SOB6F/SAkfTCH8@Nh@liMDk@xQZczTR8lyPGf1VneUbZlvPjk3vU5FddwW1R@5Bg@@ENjt6IZ99Ed3J5y7ZgBZmJGc8ngfo5duY7DBVyDQehA0YqHAyF2xBGIR6uKDnh/jfmXTt2kUFGhsIrmDCWhbnsjtKNBIKQgYgMc/atNYjNzZslqAVhxliw4Sop0F8YEKspEG8NCGup0F8@gmDeH27WFSTtylWbtxgbebYfKYU/zddvFxWsBtKFToqDPjM4uo0ZiQ7jENCFx00BzXPbEButuzmuS2Lo/703wG3iUuWKlMl3PBzmn0O5p//nrXON3SXGKW/5h4aGxQyJ/LJi02Y8b7wniRx1SRpS5rE9pNzsFmWmsX0st@NKOKDDKL59KcxmHSy@baad6HHT71wXYnK1iOrhiSC/1hE4LwOghaXV@uLvI2yAS9mr6xrLKoHEQIGuW6CrCRB0qp8dW6VNRNfPbXKuglSu0yVn/5M1inPrxSIH2oI2mvlYKaC/ldsoZFqPhRKAw0YEm1qHkevvpngR/E2mMXSwB9H2KnI4fnt/vk3ku2OSqbC/34qcVIBk77UtKcO/D9cFsf1TBwfMopyOXPc8gxRLGZCfPqjqB08vMlldt4i@fkfXly6ll36d6PS0TG/qQ5u5hoUsuQWqNWD4plUtKmx8fzBAOiUlNYYx6hec8aSw7NYGozFO1DX2dLiLJ69orLnqdnXdXYC@RkzWIpLQv96xBhtcIRBYo2i32TlywyXytx0TK6twB0yuV1m1qWBOYyN5nGkKY7B9GwmBI7lmJCxiFrmFiSzd5YjLriRKvwE7Un7eNTGAK2BP6rICCCeX90Z@s89PKgmVXRzUXkeZElDn4W1JgQkxzkovt5BhQpoqnQqwrrfLLcjYLvbnQ6nA3xDc6RchY6RqlV0GUeC4Gg6DCROPHHvTr0B9MBBTi1iEUHMG0Mr6RQGVvpS1SeqTqt2scpqlfXGK@SGjpKobd2JNw6pMmdRFkCXT8SgQhXehgGrWHg0UD8lROyK1pH9eeCNXNuAxyiuXslIIL8IRYdLNYgykmNi4CihBsij6TCG4VTOOOnGOJxTCdDix66VVnDkXKQbMXExQoi2jvACsSJ90JFrGUQiLYgmcSwrpdUCjxIhegzkOYxDrJZWaljRGLPIRRF5htaa5e0@uS0io1bCQdg0NM0CcIQRejmumzXoHWTodjnWL//2k7@zCqfVqkqjmDreqA0yA0UkibDi54H/WH0b6FE@kbaKCdx/H@Fm1D236w3bGKEmNFADcWVghglEzKdAaOi0yh/AfuMf2YYvGFUhEla1emd7Wxy8t7/3PlpD8SUCUUGiOBLBurCKPOxUMpYvFYMRRFLCIsxDWTECqUYsQuleIZjuMbnX6duGBhaM1jf/mEaL7vJ91HTndZlAiNkWO/XBe0LUrTXR6olQFIzz8M0/Ysz@mLVn0xH7Y0sSJvwcu0D86irSXugXQ6TX94vv/xlVJy1KgOfDe5WhWXUW00@5TXkhSzRbrh9m9ipWDQ1CJuILh@hbPyZkAQfpVhth7oq5K2ok6d3@4V8JwoGPDzB7RkkRw1O8ENG3GZF@PaCRy8RXvhDfdxhfz6NXABNRZx7v4kM4JysTNBqyjeTqBcP3i@/LFgO8F@KbyTl1LMeam0udjH81Z5bKyunIml8Df@YM/8BEKs1cszDyQZWK55OfRcvU7Ca7Tmb6vmKszkTTUjv8yX@mUR/pmMPqQQ/gjNacqtS1ktHmv/hLjX@WuzK7gGB@@bff@1HUx1lmz2aZ/fletJpmi72YZbX9SmJL@ioeGVZxljkVP41XE1u5M8f4zELwk6xxn8UHe5a15IH09aKfXbDss5B8WyHRC3524ZLPwvUdhSt1sSe7lbHcZ5nLXGHPWOgJ/MsZzYTF@C/mYpydN/OZaz6bLP6GkCPDh8ajC9NSrUoOp0as7Yao01/0zIt/N5OtMXc/vGqLGBcHOCpAh1JTjPYQarZhrvzTZEz5M@ZrotS6dLagemTUUpe1gGjSHgQpVTnO51bXCg4diHsptWy@WSW5s2p15LLR/XTcQ6mD3u@GJHlM6PkPgwek74zfoLkEbhvEFba2IfcETWryIb3gBAvkg@jI55ASNdADdA/EDfq7obtbrnMKyRtXklgGPrNEV@g6HUWhTEFEShLF@mGqUMFyaupC@Ce9A7F01WHpCgdL9pH8yEY5F27e3/qR3pH0KPlx7AmUxYtx/qOcBlIxordy8tghebps1E7sSwtS8VR1BGQe3f9s7haJ6rJ5SQMsC/N3/0QfdG6Auqw96A@avJLHfwyOiQOTeQIa@yf/JAR2YTnaMjJr/lM18QHvUFmV40l2iXoyqvnxH1hI2umDxNmNi4UsiTFTxhK7j8TTJzv7Yu/pweOnB3ghYzpG1DJ4tqDHYjfvyyTAxi8JFmTZBoj5KyzOGnlMXl7JK64UqPt//j3sPqMtOlbNMobp3HI/iJWrq3LnjBFNxaVHSI7PQnm@tIDWcd2yt46zJkcIBOjdUYjrNXDhhwTjiwl2@CzPNiZ/Npk2pW5ZMeO5xNR/nt0yLmOyLxPwqMMJcOoC58@pfUkZXwxl0JXVHF/vnLTXPMYPvVAuPwn0i6ag2M1m@oXvyclJpY/hqaYTr@IG6J4oQMdw1fERMAsjny410W02EJ7XBdkWnRdOuy@iX@Vue/SyHaCCzDszVIl2br8957@5rDvi8dGQQ3G86T2xEHTbW5qXuiVAVup0X5T6J72GzGDDYK1wwonI/UzUxzBQv7xxX0P4Id6z66zO4EXXHxC3a3UGcJBZUdXcQwU5V5/ye@yxYYy6RJ5L76eCmGabFSkEPhpQDvwErkpZF3uz5vwwVnymi8e0WQKOiHkuUlYIxnzW46CwATPOn0WVqmqbM@ksXpuQ4esDKoUoSEQzVzAxi3DMmbFS/Ca@UGEaQs5jaWj503WotBpv/oJ5dBRhAE2MYcBdu9r84Fnz2eEocE@WD4vVoxI6OkLojjRrpDElnz38G0d/8HIw9oNY0sgNQlZwqamk7rGkBqYVVnyRY5XQuIFmaYUbLxo01A50KBO36Duh7UkzVdLGOabnbatpRWPMDWvKxuBIe0rJQKbhw5Nham8iOjQQYbrukorEl6YLZb0/QX9aCrYMY44OYEZzNCPEQA3xpSJjmIqzeKvwtYwTYNjZB26iKyofpqKZyDK6eSbn32z@1ddufh/WRXrriWB5U0wojc1c2HBduVzYI@amY8wrtKC63B6gyz9rZ0TuaZTiYKGxXFWmKVwPdkEGnTUmvysdT/BL6khqoWBdc5R9xdzhZcnrQg2p1jSJXuEpXxGCLM8bCEcQSSnmymIzsxhIurxx0LNYWrETo5EzauSMizD0LKORh7IYBvI03TYcotO2NpxHgK/OGr0kFoqg/RLjU7ErouWqrjPac4gKlIUhTCjSWfcwtfam0Whj00ogQEJcQNBz@@3pIFzPJTe8ell/6T2Kh1LtUfwlyYD3CiAw2oIbrFRmayKTLxZ4le6R20v41cxZ9VKtVKf/1fj/Vkklqv/XFxNrcch6PLFWSvzv15J4iCObLhbVa6u4Ied@tSTG8/DYH63kloQ@swWd2eiPkF9Qnwf8PhyMvPHYDSnMkThyR/i4jYFfPR9vLND5F8bVgd8vXPIvsq6QC36KbT0PWoioJRFVxnNhXduyYNyHY38Sio8GXkf9xhjlN1fVVzAP0I1U4LrEAwXABMlnbtT3PZjMd8O9Ed5LVNFjcujz787A71SHIMq7E3LlGMCaBwjPr0ymoyq5m3JHPXwWJzOE9gto2jFUB13rtQCshd2yC0h5gYvuKa1ns37fIuct7qD3xEXGDW@PhI6kstsjvqMdHFu4rS2JR8CErbO7FeXDRHvpohF3RV4@xpUHHM@ZNAbyRqQv1HjHWJakmWGhUrR8ryfXf1aFHqChlFUgtswu0InohxG8UuWUBVgxJFYC@4hB@pgxxrMi6hGGCHXRskQ2oiiETKB2RJ@y0iiBKpLns1cC9hB7paxoXRumlXnG@jq698S7Mqde0DuFh3ZS9bV1jM1BPcEBxWmST8P1NcwhB5WBwIhz7JvG7EfRkS0BQJ4QCoQIPPYEPTJ0npMSKV7WweGB9FdReXg90UGXaAOK8YL3VyP3iKKkiJOOx6Fgel5AAFiyevSRN5ZDVIqRamd6BKw2rQWKrOIFwdS9cWttlRpEcY0UaM/vxkBXqoAZXctWqXHH4XCge3E7PBYD96U7YP9v3GyK/cKLkujMltsnXjffLBDpwFDGegqjYN8ucdr2zv0Hdw52tkuiXL@B4GygqmFtY3A5u0j5ZMAhyQiL8PKtdG6uMpHbQSm/Vc0XZNO3zGEvmg1WCGDPmqAcN7bzDhWTN3OMGESmHu5VJR1vUcd2Q11tXG7YlOkEoxZYanDVyl9aspCksa4lJMHY5ghlCtGhAV@w8SwAZe4VMAJyd2uhEIahhIhyrY2r5bJeU@v0qwwba7m8yXbm1j2Qw1@I/P50FNtt87R22iIPmxx6y@Ot7Wqe9oWK1RDHTv6tIN9A7lxzTi/taeFUhfgb9bEVNg/cgX93rubPniqtFRiQQrN@WCjIhPz//DeIfWeRWcDADgunyF9/5CiXsBXe1HfYg6ad59tgKPZRJXRn4T3aXEMnbOgCHb83r1BI0t49OHt79kdmHWO7cErazV3HuV44hSonY7RDGcNm6B4AxkID0/qxtEjkePZshG5xl1H@@urDB@/BlO@jf6kgbH5wuHytWsrn4YgnDSQHI32I7b2Hj/EmYVKo0I3C/Yk/lOMyaetKKviwj5bD1PqShV2r4iqEnfPIDWXvg7vzg/bRo/YQJOY2DEH8Aqdtav1gmHvU5TfHyLHik2sVTo8cgjqeuP0Gc0JngfPSPio0QvhzbFZxA6pwVlYIewiFHHQgkBh1bwSn9XsHDx84@Y22QKxOyqrIFzuaOIBQiGBsTCKBNkY6GE4XqSpku00iGPhXzFub8b5sVNub@cbZWWZ7HvjtHnv8ykcE3LOnJUlxE2dxShuTiArmY9fBBD7a3t05sEpQFmVfTKQYR3PatNgZsaPqYHLDnYKOwPkThHGc1bffpjQsMg0cZ6VWK6B6yBlgIx8QgJYX1qRxNmk7PVsPZHvsVejq3J1xXcScrFRWqu1RcALsaLV@s3b7eu0df4LvBj036L4dwBbitDGkrBfO30ZDflInO/IH/bf73gAfrK6uLq/teXd/56u3n9zctrud3wIe0noe@PiAPxmbDZi0T6T2H@yxky5TFzViBDi77eq4/cKvrvZq3bXaWv1Wz711w12rXV/r3nCv3@7cvn27219d6/Ru32rfutHtVNFtNBWpDEl50GLyx2r7l6s2izFbW6nd7vfr9Zu3ejdu92@v1K5fX@2s3ejVVlf7a/X29es3eytrndud87m2qD052GDVvotnR3IHfiubucst7O2ydOF/AQ';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O@]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvw/WWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 6  \=>axfnuen le._e _=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Numun Cr Uu8 gutyIO 0; nd e
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;r=pure;q _=r 0;data D a=D_ a;d(D_ _)=r 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212]!!(l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+k+q?2+(d.D_)?3- 39);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score : .001042

### Explanation

emotif___ is a brainfuck substition that uses emoji for its commands.

The emotif___ code is mostly inside the second line of emoji characters. The code looks like

which translated into brainfuckese is

```
[[[[[[]]]]]]+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+.-.++++.>[
.
]
```

The  was already preexisting and opens 6 loops, the frogs close the loops. That is the followed by doing 7*7. 215 is the, printed using increments and decrements. The  is a loop to protect the  (print) in the emoji-gramming code. With the frog coming just before the data portion of the Braille code.

#### Other changes

Cubix is now inside the Multi-Dimensional brainfuck loop as the cube size changed. `nd e` added to incident token string.

Answer (score 8):

## 230. COBOL (GNU), 10800 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JArwNFIACUCBBggCBbjYft3mH3eSQ7Nv3DslGF4ACUc1CFbqqQALN5o3RrGOsWSkc2tmxQg/v3pFsrWXvRqzCYUdoY7WxEdLXDcX@htYnh8Lh@QfyOSczqwovkn1nRrIdAglUVubJk5knT548J59N3ev@3d8l8MMOHWt0YTk@8w3PZ23XvDLcHHs6Yk900ysVl2MxhNp0LwY9w/a9SizBNMZs45rt2S2zDX7Mdy4N23xvuBBWZKzvOheu3mN@V/fhxYRYbNuwPvQ@@Kzl9Hq63fYAcpmxQx0CO4PWJdObnu/qLd90bAhaYeylbem9ZltnAGG4fdfwCX2JsQ2j1/dHdXhZZey543oGptgyPM9BiLUoRBkgdNd09jdffD6BaZ2xz3XITN8yhhPJawX2yjTc9kQMTWNfnuzuTvoW2fdUx2a7WIyJoGX20vV0S5/Ev8I2B76z50/6l9jmhWHrrJhbzxUnA1fZU1efirLGXENvd0zLyJl2i6msa1h9w2XowzqOC7XkG1a5UC40NsOYuRbGLYeBE2hr8sN098KDQOfKAKcB9dc3jTbruE6P6bZ3DSlp64UQHtGuM2t52Z@gRbEQqZaiFn0pRl@Woy8rTNtvTLJAsYS@mwd7k/6rrLg/6bcGOW5ddqbrplhmR05/NOm7zp6b@7MYb7nAdnrOW3PLaUOZJ8KixVkujjeAFtQPNC321oOstA3m2Wa/b/g8EGrbcCkYCM8s076M8fZ26DrtQcu0LwDOgOT6A5@q1Iu1IFqd9UWrzaGDJYgJOBhk4djpGdEsetBcodK8vtEyO2aL84Yx9A3bg@r2cswE8lyblsXahgURQuytLPMcNvAiXk1L7@ZauRjyFqbCepcWM1mr32c8CIoBWdotlJmBBGPvIdzqemzY7zHP7EGw33I6HcNg741@F6LH2k6MwafVnyhW8LZkAIxtSNIYfWjTSBoHSQ10khS6dnWgresJGvhmDyhr@kmPGbpnonyDKJ5ht4mq/UDyOcDLUYKxKxPaLBR94BJuz3Cp1RBeaGGuASj1oJ5T167pAzWRGpvs0NBdduIahsLr2PBaeh9rOJokJOZgCj4WJEeVurGR3DnYTULl8hg5vQ@V6S6ffP@LmM5yNbbUqMK3Fo9XYzsvttnN0hm6uYQFBui7KV1htW@Ylz87M@A71Jr5C/c2BlhjQBWL5Z2@n9fVPmRQ9SGDeR2d6FKvirm@FUmYbUzURYTlOFQbagPkB/sySyVrDVwX@4KQqPolFNpy7AugJxTWHdhID5utFqAKWg50AllmXAHVQHhSHTnXROGTrgmV5mGVRIQS756IoNBBARsLisp0PccaEBzE9HzkZaAKREWMex32JevopoVRIBxR8Vy7hjewfIwzsNtY8z3TNto5JrNBLdYFPr6C5HRASh7A@r1Iu6RMATBUhENFxaCPv/OH7YsLwLPZajluW7Drl6zttKgj1Smz0BUyZFjH1i3KFsBlMXUeHRK40i2zTRJCt0ciCcoEpXrtDKw2cyBB99qEVtrVQU4b0LhavsGZ3Bn4kMcs6@mXXJqYnHOh4D29CRVLCVDaVGyVPdmCWmoZsQTxjNob@J0yU/s7LOnlX6ceV1KPF88MyJySU9JL@fxFFRgulyYveEvexTlfbo71Mp6ve47ZjvVHftexi0xtsXir5vQNO5Ucw5HMJt1mUsmhlEspVbPWynVMu51KbgAv1iHhpFJt1VqnZuW8OhE9miSguUY02FyNVEuJx0DkUKO4yvdAFclBf/ClKlyRMMdrIMkxOBfxRsJM@l1xjwQpOsiXDjIIyKGcZxlGP1XIaQqKCYSbWW4MmFXSCRyiwBXzPJNMJDPRohMGKOlYQbGxnpgOii2r38XuEIhie33oCVzk3ZYO3ONhh@CDAphlTeJr6kVAspBMvDaSoAA0QZBKPqImyZscxldRUAoMYRMab8lGO9KQQQhAW/a9KWlsOahYUJ6wmwHRYWOi@gVUDUTmBdnkBeEpkc94kS5tECiIrWmwsto0oRFgcwOZLng@UjYAXy5yGMDGG0lE9vT0EWBp8W41bDDM7EBb6oF4cEesZaDMAeFj8A4FExlQ@/NAS2ZOhxXUYqk03sammpjv5jfVH4CQfp@/syVh4aONCQUN64BSbun2xUC/AHnh2BBFb7WMvi8EFZTE80EUTfY35KmKzjPndWNLTybTpk5EqhZhGijkee2JrlBH6SKUfBX0GdQaueXA2qYLYskaTaYOAFcTicffIMhYBt7E52RBagDAZMbQaA18kGrAwNdds9UFnsXc2Vwu8k5oMnnwiqYOkl3tBEljZrT6o2Islw@8MBtzUahYo9N4oHNFVPUxD6r8qMfdmHWvNwOxE2QROoKIby6v54D37sHZc2xnBlIgZIAWQcZDeD2AJnaMCiV0XFLtosYaaJlBFUGdgdSAlg/81/X9vleBfsL0u4NmDjglf@KO9vwDG5kl77sj03e4u2k5TRDLHrTPvEwh3xo0zeFEgcgvqMO3XuwKFLCOx2rQc78bANelkh0PBCb5byFwJChOgptQ8N84ABJQDgiV6ngkindBqByP7FYqPsaU8SyLY9uNK@DAiAFpvkDlbTybb8FrMpcIFs1MLo9Qec9tkUON6KSIHsEpW7GFsaI9MI@xhXgcfjq65RnwtAeWha8Dm0u5FNcVFHYTW1gA0Zai5Mxe3zJbpt/goezRI6FTsEUwD1Ft6qDOpECcBWGH50CgAIzofjh0zneOSdlNKVCQhduxhA3XdVyert91nWtGHggWixJ1y@mhdGevSOFCDRosYtNG6070pdSV6jNViKBPJX05mcy9dUw7dZNcXFxMVpJ16DEXFx@DawNdj9GVAddjcqnkQrgcuihGllwYekox0O88eXsqMQ@Vc2wOQ@zt35v9lH5aqSyfZ/VTTTyL@FSAztBjALSKD8CTVGo1dCpKvH4NBc01O@Ol38Je77jlmn1BhC/0K52/CyosExmg4hwXDYMqKi9306RXc0G7AGOg1U25ybPTwtn52c1ZO3N2m8xibKWq15pQKEgv1ctduM4A1BDldKWiaueKcroMykezliwk06lUWbUgIV1RPisrGZ1TO5U0oDdMnZ0lgaiCPqetrkv4htmiogSkgnygwgO6diqZuylD@k3lXMkkIa6SzILpVksmgTItJIJHhca2NEagg6PvccJsZTIxat6Oe4nfqe4U/HJguI5HPxy8f4@yi@NoBhxmDXSu5fUFQH7PlrA5DJwwXmVQs8NQjlIauyB7to7HRyl6l9AzspZnoRqpujwNeM2nuWebHoG2XGF7ZG3YoCoBlUBTagdWre3YKrZqaZg40YTIlEcI8kO9AftEcwwGEXfMIRh3ILNHUolF3Qv12C3HBjPLyL2idh1nIJJwzMLIzdRkD7lKkGt5IZ@BzgrOvqW3QHKNozuLszNACG0pn58dolSnEE@quWSR3ldGUApauo30a5tkcQ1Mr4vkBa0Y5ZnbAaqiuQV6nUFU22Mt0NcugNLG0PS5/QW8eoxRnuleSkGNf5NrzKioo7aHmZLjN6SKOS2wVQ3Q@jCUG/5sx74yXcdGIud2ADU0qirWwQTyWeQFNtrc3Ctuz6fvLORAsSlvLULbKNZJ4ra8FsvbjuVcOCwNAMiauRxn7D0bx7lAX/f1PhgS5nsi0OaFY48meNAwgoHD1eXActIRMk/wubcgz9jsQocAc8p8vPeDHehQtVKhAPmXbwX6BIWMYJksI3q2WAggRr8t5BusyR8Y/e5obPwP@YOPAAA/OQZvmHxMRgdlCHIlWvh7ihpt5NwH2rkMakvXrLLvkHaLw1BRC3Gs9GP9Lm82UMLEhDf6SlKMIZ2q8LB@UXCd5cfkVmD0qp2e4@v5L3Ndj@FPDHU91WRxL59cTOZVFX/jFMSKdZZvG1d5lFIh5uGO0ZqJe2gYrTyGophm0jGTPDJwDmnO4GPTDxSTPyUNgpiT5b/IZJjq8NwFafNMQ3d10h0YMaPVdVj8DJTlaMni0Ld0wepTgfKgyqCGHUQTMyEx3xmAgdI2LLNn@ns0cmvZqIXnSHjnUGqJUBxzDhEcmgaoltx0DvscHF0NOyD7gsMfgSQnrGCs5jhJXaOdT4fYnjuOCxaSxzSyjosB6XsiIO94/XbOHwICHmtniHqFFzPoyV4cbO80DjdPntXyA8/NW2YTZETbaPTALLOgOcz5YN5wrGsHeMe0nZ4JJZIo319aR47j13gjubTYwz4JjChx7G839veeHm0efS0yh7g8szewdMxjZWkCIMBxTDB3omk5TcdSL@zBXEygTRw8PdiXWL54ub@32djeOTw4iaB5O7BMXRvm@5cX8wr0BYIwLVfgpD@w2uPj@mRwjdnDQtig9VBlYGUxVYVfFf14omhf5DAAlT3sHlUVxzN1HLF1WVErrK@3m3q5bKy2Wysrax29026vFLVyqVMuFUsF@FlbXTfYBwJXVWNIYxDg4vY9DoVgGpB5emi5FZGlQklvasbMTPGgO7JltMutcqmkG82VVkuHXLVWl42VTqGwvmIUi8ZKc6Wj6VqxeGe2eCpS3wITrwX602hmhoLQO/LUKpWMtZV1fb21vr6uF9fay3qxvGYYq2udlULBWNUKnWZZKy/fmadINlDRC996NLICMgCNcAoEUZyCx1jj5Jn3uqCvtIvF4mqr1FlfLrZLhZV2c71QKreb2preXDcKnZVlrai1W0WtIuPiSCXIrC6wTx5H2MDMlkGqBoFKTHbtUYajiT85GSzE39IyCry@nMxFhVwErGDAQEzl4pCn8F9F/x7O3eZasYtWC8UsvQaeArBMgDiFm3Ob0nMdPYPJ27FpTRDQQmrPCp8fSWC@0Qq3iPwap38j5bjRNPK/8judMe8ieV@q2IFaofcyefPJ3/FpV1HYqaCZwAG@FcLHJ41n4psKmgkc4CtxfDjZPBvdRMgs0ADZKiHDyemZuCYCZgAGmNYIU3RCOwwrU9i82WyR1szguZEC3OuEG2etQ1Q0hy28JGCR14NmNfRGr2eGwNInEsRUC7phbTWMXAoiOxNRHTP0DsA5WYtWA4ydQaSdSJ9oUBCJU1DOeUd5ssgJ6Dr9UaQp3RR52XumaKMR5l7mbYFmcdHkcccCOefz2e3GWz5D0hCT29jSufA4AZ153wFLZ9/EuYLOmDSJBVb/WSwuhy7GB6/CkGI4NcPUq9lzSvEoIi4oTfvSIWM9cDUKOa2EWAIUvUtrOmYHjEL6GQOdytR0CNc0es0O/cwAQPVocjSQAmioVShpoBTp@SN64KDrrByMDx@PJd80OgOwV/NN00b3PWDqepkgO82mOQ8UKIGLBeRzBliFHQ2aI1bMreQ0OUCB0zXQn/Gx35O9AwJs6mRuj885sDHi@wPXh1ji@Z9/2IZKmK6irj4iqz1wNGzjmvijM7fGRFR8oZ/ZtRvqZ0QYct2HsqXjNK9uBY7ZqKn2VbWruz00jkV1A4PiD3DCHbzGc@4a1qBtyOfsRCqMiDw@t8Fss8daM6AJdmIahidGwyGWo7eJDHzQwjQokouVzavBGHLzPaKagoiZl9CM2RIWLk/wuwN/wH9xRcJ91Wj28XtXE10Weh/YMXrTNO6ob1e/HLQdFdRxKi3maXUGbFhwGhtUO5Z@yZ0NdM4uOS@ba15cgJolnvPArrtggNLIQf6aHvexhGcPvL7ahHryoc3QG7WC3h0puBb/nQdiisV9gWM@1UyLfh5Q3wFfEaeApkuExtVHaoRo5gSZLb05wvGU7qczGCZI@iCIm1orkyksYw8aTDWH65z6/fnxsdul@Ovrs2PzdU@cJLNs4Dxf76Ty8Woqs1gBdU/FQp9l9nRLLbYjzrnCXI5Uh64ZoDS4prYs3QPW8kV1GFdQffRzF7tjp9QC29gNXXcwe5gdueJg3uS1kFiiQbccy/SwVVvzhOfkfF@YJq48o58wKr5NE7ZNKqbXVQPXbLngtHycOZ7DaA8QcHzSFqfFI5yTc@YRreVc43euVtF1rgz@O7uPez8zVw@QWKpFLGG2ZnYm7dZ9nIqrj@hnNh0vZ@bLb1kz/cfbgByHitqtD@Rrz7Qcjx3T711kATXa8/jvbI6OUtDUbZWmn6Lu2dFEpvosJ4bC59Srbl041mr5Iq/Dz9zKH7gd7BPE86HSL5Bemna/9JKqkWNr4jlX7F/m3cv76o7mj1xcIxBx3tEDzxJhYg50fgHBiMCFP7MLt1soU8xcng8vzKsAt9W91kfy@R16lnnUlT1Lf0SqNmh@GGG9DA7f5er3d0lt5e7U2g8TT1No1@4rRKRyLy0DOjL6napSVixonxhDKxQeLqw61sAYGDNl1UHzrYGrve8wQB6eqYIoxpIYksaBMhyQDqDeC9PxQbnGPhzf7hQwumVCI79X05kp7/qgnvfR2j4ExyE6piNe2IP@WOWOGXD20d2U6/Zly3baY5nEkE@VSOX79akxbd8z6HunXcXtQJyArC0XCgWh30QmGcZe7rK3loO4b03@O5Yw@YQpj42SzMAZjihDVZuXnopjuw@TRsV5xj8Br6/nbdM2/BH@zquCWdK16TjWp1QZCNm2ifoaaKE4G3df1U3pQmKxGQuHOTwcJGl25g1w8A5IGKJAPbSx76r96Aj0g6pVxXUE0CovJl7vHvKJjGfflwp06zSOhAu6hHuewU6DJ1qunFu7swVy9dVpGpbOH8PVlbvwreeW78QXqChCL6YJR5yk5NOS4TR3YkJO9UdALLMNRk3X6Bn0eoc1oLffDjz5mAs0dPA7IzhHk8Dz4vVNEAw2/o5NgUZUJ9@xwQzzdffCQDvGwqUKwneeMJaTDjOJu9fTLwy@4@suaRmOauDKZG79hc7Z4xsVvqitBdH4epy7WQEa06Ux8uRzJsLnoxbU56B3/6jcRLtv0Tqo@xp6Lj9zruUe3dDuOl27a3RdahzB27zmARzp8716dxUC8t/VvUtcik0yKjQDu16UupZjWQ@hLspILjEdpzMzXzu4jaoNUT8J70hvQoB43DviB/07EYk6@nltp2sMoJvyHN/pGyq9zQO1cICI/86TpHL@67uOPN05KgAUkc/viv9ee/RCd/x@nx6NvjXw6IeiqrT7bVZV7lIyD@EK0@frwTjvGhdOs9U178tS09B927zMy1Eg/nqnNduPUMFk6jZ65ywTiOeOcsgNtWj4MT725lVpZIZnZum3Bq47ul9CjC9rCcZs@VQDOualL6ZOZwSTPoALHuXCvjvmO8RM61z2IrUbVWzVKIDKos0dQxpbPyrEGE35zdGIJspNmYlMs33K4KdYhULDgGZkjBb8x7hmbDZ@Zp09E7IOzMnUs8GFp9zPu9026Fz4MxPh5gVufPWY7zjMs5zryNg1dEm6LR4ze@hgXvKu6ZTSnfMpubyYDVWNwdwhMsvse/yXqZ3iTCzTs@vTUKPZJrKoobbR4VMe6LpPy@s5Lu5PAnVCbbmG18Jhc5TEXHfiUsd2LkAiqxYLgSXszCJMT@jP0lPGezv1qxfGhY5rXvdNXP5qedMdIGCenNt/COLvD3TP/P7A8Y2ZOCfn@B@C8rl@YbaejdWCRCipKxZI8sdYI0Cv6Yq47poebRORjtkNh7MZzdfPMNQmRuaD7cp3j6BEdCSxqpype0yuPg8cODeA4frMtMY1UDFVP1fWmT6NuornzHLOXg9x1/DD9aDXH3jiMTt1WpoUHX7uXZK/d22CIFTfgdxlXd3yZw9RR0ZdQbcSnWHonKdx/8C0nAv2g3KBgSoGAg4V8DmM9RS65kPdhxZgz2BWSv@Bc6A4qKG6vHDvgBGMZaaatunfPYDj@zrYRPKJBeJqF25qzO/jb@7Jp2JQT2ZTZf9OiQ@9@qhlgZVzH9Th1/dAGFv3dy33zN1UsL907IGv4lbwuzqJ1Ts7iQobllcjXMBS3995/lKRzHDRbfGlxveplgbYdwPPGoWuuUsHZvCYaYMONl/MTseQhsK20dEHln9Ei2MfEG@zj/uvSKpvO7MMmsMRdDKfZBVBPzHobRstnFB8UB5eOM9BR4Oeqw9ytXdk4EKACVEyPzJG3XdaugU0az8ouWNCP6NbCO1pvW80oe6t0DVbCZuHfFv39VnEpMHBzuBTBpA902oa7lsc@ou65@ls0zl6ZgzJ9JjPTVzxUf1Wi6vZOBw31ogi1niFHfcdvin7jva8CR3DJw8H5HDx@FhXN9MQmy7hwRVfRWK0@R5Abxbpj4ymY90vZWyTLxvQXdPw8vumPRiSH1NBU5tt2vBV1IXcGg5oeF1od9cmWNLB4mpcgcZXanuhhSDW9NhXukeT@bNtl7GF3A9fKtTV3ZaDs2LC8YlzYpG9ZXebGuFKdb7ooAmMMwQZp7cG8oCCqWTFzgE6riPY2O1lxZ4W8DNdsQPUy8mjWxK0/4fwyZXoLIGbzwdo6viOm2MEl0rpmYyixHgknHC@sAFMQtHhGbixnp/L4THoTnyCNTvs9JQt3QwrhYp2y2osXomz83OOFT@0zXtn2KeTL4549NMl/by2lFTV5FLyzK6wQjIANyzQmGaC62OwHZMePL8hCZit811e6JYlrvKDA7wuHcrR1e22ZbCXNs0KQN/n8u3v/GyFE1zY9ld/2hZnlVwYUNieCVYLEASP6nF6Rte5fszTFalDT6DjWSeIAxRci@@8V7c2GWhefqvLjyhxrtnL3ZOyOPhAnAsEL4fcYg1ywSsXB8xx65vPK4/nJtjGJBIOYslCQT8/6NnQitp@18uxY5N2tQ3ccGW4OCzK9l0cEWtn2R5rG7iQiDYr0iCw5TiXtIEBc/JXf8qPe6Ati2IrmUyejnmJpIg7EzU6Y6HVcgaQa4nkveE6AiSFRAZ1d4BTLgw1IPJXcCMfnUMBHKnKUxgoGX4Uw9bmMVN3WBKPPMJd01Wzk1raPPr8y9PCee0b1ssb//mHeeVGEC7@mbq@6sWzTIJUb5GxosElCA5Dkyy@NIzzBIP9nKbova95fQCJdM5kuKVT8pjj9EWroZN06OCYgBvFhuwUuqme5XEMPTqEhxjWuKbjGGjjkI19N55uY3vQwOBVIdS81dWWUgM@C6Ae@6wECeKRFjq4@LE9tMMRjxbAKEtD9oF1kcmgK9BKBXjjhLTwNIte7alcYbocXfmb3zaaA1oCd1XMFZdrVJylRm2jTi7oZRw8Veb09dmwWFDPhms753lPEvXsbPhZofgVUN1xIdajPLa8nRfbN0u5euHDB08fsXj8NlnlK5VBTCzdHO4d7hyfbJ68PIZauJXiZ5fv5ZCyBrmINot1HYvO6wG6YB/zCfIneMPd8ym2pLMNPExOUWLRbT0EKmgdV@NL3BkRTWOx74k@K75nRMKnAYRM65hMctQe9LZYh8BsSDUs/KCPpw4xEVecnEJcZqKMxwYUEAbXg8@QpUSqOKsBsVQg1gNJxeYX9jH3ewjF7sVyN9kezwRBigXpnQbhvIgzSXD7Kyl3HzrKX77cHMvd5SaYO8oNoIGvjLO7ubf/8mhnPBrwGD1J6tbWS2I/GxfO2NL42gF5VAxtIxcRcQalFmdxisBfRWc2wI2lTcO/NqBYQji2ejwycSjlPx4LGRMoU8PjFs@rnBapFOUAdZAqFmtiu13HHEayKPvoCLobXsRACOzGA9Qy47m4wJygc/Ny@JHFQKyCXLLpHZIQF/I66UXVn6xscVg07KMHHm9zc7qqoNfxGPxHeiXpKp6zIRPdmXbOVFaEr2XYF1BgCatUeR/Fljgh4ks87/Egv3hmG@Sp/VanwUtaoSw2hkEvbel9PCBKQL9wfKPC3g0c2govhUmgX1zj0JjOjyekqm3pWBraYm/7eNiT7LcI397ucQ21M66akXyP8tzAxo4KgCKHBe7gnjtgNr5vjx87xknuiBOuZFdJJoEnTrQJtASPXZme2bQ4f3VQx7FAUmJpRMHxsE06BIFtWh7oJG3ovkFD8bGrBeUkRztm@LYZ1WbxBPBkLlAZsyweQ1ivNn3iEXSl16Cut97wyEsER5i9CM7kxqKqAuUuwIYRu28qeNYkTVhUmO8OcFVMPTkVRWahQi616/esCOCMs9/OjPzH3/lDft7bmQ/unwj3sPAU3n5LvHXA/dsyRNPg7Z8Hb0V4@yl/e53HKps@5EokLwzsuduLgC@fxKfKhDJBnq9JZQlqG2v6y71D5oEuy@uypw8j1YQSBnkOzEngvx4wxRXVMYLzFMIqDPGkTr8EFgG@Av5A9QY1GkrPcM9TeNRRJZ/HjOPwZo5WJhlDPnNIJx@9G@CJf6CE5VdLqytaHjKpXkmEdITFBe6R4AgVpQIyMXZl9mtvwIzb2Nhgca@lW0Zttcp5I7@kv16OvwkyugSwMW4onDKIA1HCGBBWF9FSS3pGUzAqdmRJLYkyre1wVgNtMEUOAFHQ25ab3kHddASpgI9tY@iTxjSSBhAIbJt2dRr83EeJSAVEHDeeSzfZHMPND2iVRxpoLloN8VcIdoxglfgsZj19zc78M/tcnE/IgPF@PoN1bXD/sxmHFnLOwkM9pk/LS02edYelYU@ObQeHNnYhtyxVzBeX89qqEuHQuEAF@cWm/gFQQuMGYdEyzLdO39vc2tn74uDweOrUN4JMToIlWbK@kTlTc9nT88CRDPI9TtSnu/nj5093JSmjuQqHFxAiXBk2mc1ZqU3mdE7qr/g@k@m0KWAqIa3wUMS05ELdpRWV09jD0HwEcIsvc59KNaXc3J6eb9TP7MRU8h9mnYSZyKWRucB15tE5mMnJbGIWgzOyT/CMbC8n909quHkSt9b4zmW4tVN4RAI4uMQCEiCWy0uoGRwrM3DAx2fC0x2K/JBuj0QfH8Oh8wmDHEUgT@Rx3ti0wmO1xHlSXd3rWmYzBn13G89Y42doyEMigtM3cl7fMv2UEqPRjxpqQCDEUuJQ72FlmKP5kBSdhkm4suyuI6okPiUGjQDwJQ8HXpcdOn0WDj1tG9J1BIoI2x7wkXODfTHoAVyHHkcGilgDVBMVIgOhkkFWuUENLUucUDXM4ClgkN4pnlMlCp7rtUupoZLrGsO2eQECPKVkoaV/poFGFexnxULTqVV2EmQcp/DnuL0gStJPOqhsGCLXT/WcabeNYQrPK6mcg2qK/snrV1dJJT7FA3Ramjjcqj15bJpsiLovWkR45NhEY1tfDxrZ@Ll26@t45gtuzYVqgRSPfXcfnNA/pTo9vc9SAzrPz2M5Rq@ps5Sd9XxXYWqdH11gs0yGDGp4UAAozAjaIRcxDkvh8bepfA1qB309u42P92afnWq53Dm4KRGFLeFg2hZ05TgMpcTAQIIoFUJbw7plFcwR594c5zyIg@ExOpaJ4aF2M4LpGDqcXIJ2CrSgUrP6o8hxNmEL5FRdX6@I2hgXNesM2GJayufygHaGCJEKKtBX7LQEquExzQC15RptE8TCk@8Ztm0AgYBnejr0wfoAmMxVsvIU/2x4rC@lkOBZfCa2bkJGx4/73UneWDhns5Sv0rhM9Rb61Ddn2Kl2RLc6yv/X@Vy@epNasmqjPCg6Sj211K1pmeV0JrNkp1NLNnb1jx7hcM7tEmgSjRxYR0MAUpcspQr8DJpHbcmuLukbqaV2rZimGPAK9tkNRPjGy@dulvTb/NIj6Kmz4OPyxpta8ujEuEIup91C/rCFLOWzwDM3eCwZneePyS@ZmQzmIbfUwAx8kz87zpDMPjvO08hRVSii@YueaG4TUjWoiakLDDgBhbeoaBDsRRTsYhltQwKHh/0uzwqbo3vwhL@HOxMYLY0yvKjmHx8PebhgEfIuSUcg8fP5@JF9QMBhCoiIr1ldUUCY/N3fJbRVFk8tPV5ddjLJUqEKP1q1xErss6Wz4kqCJZ6ApZ5Px934zdm2esWMTnH1nXqqd3Lvzg8vDw@/Us5SLJnYOngd11YAdI2t0/ehnzVWnPNhn/ZJJNL5WCKf1h6t5fNv3rwBdRc@p/VcPQqVO1dO1eT5aWoNXupra@nsajmdfZJsYE6UVLGoHDNmmnl2Zva9dhu@Tpcu0kgl@OfxY0oLbE/4Z9xPpC8c8gVBhG/iE@Gu9FKCna3pejqzUnxiV3PFQvGv/nzxNntz2Nj4q9/o5Y1FfBzg4ye3z9F9rJU@W1z87OnTlZUsEI@7D39w@PXm5ubKdrZ0eFp6vKIWFjf@8j8uLhaLG8X84rnnaefJ08uv4sXCSjz3V3@cPDz8fsPzsP7ws8w0cOJvGb4aK5XYJXsPn8sOw39yv29H3Dq6m5332EGCslwjYZNMlpaTx6@TWNz3CU3TEiP6axAZFplWf7z2X3528C7hJ@rF/CsXnn7iXWK1nOBOcMDbsny7StQTGwi2epsY5Wu1GjjX/su/g/j1LwAPhow24KdekrhWR4m6WqMoHxL1VXBoxSKk@3/@8IexRH2IjFDf22XFejHNeUUrP9IeBXV0ltDKKwdPwFt@wHMYfsjQ1bTimazPSHVj1QbeXSg81CtzIn5BvQdcxQQ3kOOhcJDvxA5@/vp//@vf@@uf0d/v0fc/4J0Vq4tP3mwzZkAPjJ9K5UlQujxbK8cdB1s5fPYD/6OcCp9cI@BUfFVFyRLlWrbBcxWwcCLimKBD8MsESYL3T4SLJeS0Jkqg87BZx@son8TLc5s95x/bhn/4ylf0QQ9w2QH9EiFtEyFJg8TZpJ@sjOCFSVnAPgUulviG5WeLsnroT0XguSbH80jJwrIRqzyGzyL80T98glf8XSQf4U0g059F9t0/scRp4vT8/JmNf813@Lf/Hv/e@fh30sK/o3f4d/Ie/458/Dv08O95E/@ishyYFiRDJnMEKqNg2od8XsI3l2uIt4B5E7HEr/TDYtAczjPq7e1p7vUwU62Kf9CjqsEbfrgLcnR@q6obr@uZzCnl7LQusrihrhysHrAn53Wea/rNNV5vAPbMxulGzdmib65Rh496/rp@ujGOgZCc1588yWCDfQII6kvQMDY26nV2u3Fbvz3duL3d2ID/Dfq9FU/wvd2Y@qdH@JkDE4ZDSqenscQNMkANf9LstDfsnNNRPjX1VFstnavI7m@HHWi8HmMVLV1cXsyXhp@t7hRjiWI8nk9jxA/Y44DesB5LoPa9zpXwdfJ48/Hb/xW/Zx@//TfwCgnj/U4YinzCQHtZelywClcF7VK7fO4chP8HB0MIMIeFt45b6Ba6WhvFd8F4WRgVRsNCzznQ2uA04K/QA6dZ6AwLFwW7YGvaaDiGav5/78Dxnx84gM2BmP6w4CPiQgeeFwcHzwFfB9J@C39moVAYQiaHhSv4L1jYmdDZpfT80FDOYqcs/sYA9SWnJXOFZG41mTTPS6v9d/FssnF2mjyvJvLe2VmeK3asuFKlM2tvbxuNnRfbjUYeWf2snnmSUZ/Ap1bPbIjH40S9@visoiKLSWZL5Dcen9WXVXSvZoB/iuiX@cRPiBGe9cWzGJiqr17h99X11TV3kYNcZ@j/qsGD4ZsnL3olL/hc5ecgGHMwUJJ/Tf/tg/93/T9/yVKn5wqw@s3tRoo@Cv4pys3tza34rSuplHhJbcAfesA7Rrm5raOTgG7AdZpSzpXbW@4HvyllgyOsYxobdYocAkLzTvBUz5JVxsCoS4nJqLOzYaGgVJvgEwxL6x9oXkOp0oqPpSbORYEho6UVAimtVKsrwr1WrlbLwq2trlar6QCqAC/CCUCGp7eqyOjVRF/BPHD2TxVwvIsOH0@mxEn1j/t9MEq19cKHD4FXo9E23UYD/Zc/fDiDlpTEBR@19RL4FMofPkDzSypgsL5wxFTjOpifWr4You/qnu77buq92c@eJXEpn3eWVOhM1UIBgTE@K21srK7U66sr4F4tK0o1vsRXi6QuMuuacruUj/NigCmZTIggrbymkO9tEsNZYoM9rgOHe/hhN7cJojZbKSmp5shQAg9tfZ37sJXVVDmzLv5qiwqrp5n4Oz09Xc6spNfST87Pz4fjH5QV1Ru9pt3WbvQKDnLcVlvibG5cjq0/erS8DsQpF6pnsUZje/Nks4EXVOHsLUpe9CSpE8OZub6bPKURqdL6@SkW5/wsmaxUn/DaLZdYIlkVcGoS5Bcrr1OpE2D2mh3chzEErIg38k0n@kxbW06kY31aQrNWYG2chXSZ0@ksgifUC2vihLFnWJY8yfzaca32tdk2FmOJw/3NrZ2TbHED@qHi7uZWtnj88mlCw9dS@E7By/h@tLO5ffASIhzu72we73y@9@XOy0Pwx3OP4dM71I2B0TCuB4NrfG8Y9NkyPf3tW73fb/ThM@xwcYefjz//8cef/zcf/@inH//oxx//6Pd@8e3v/Ri@fwrfn/LnT//tegl/f/HtP/@Tj//qj8DzP8D338P3z3/x7e//kH/p/S/g@58ifn8hvhE4/oX2Wk/jB2q/XCxn0tAfpNfXgQPIdyMGaf3WL7792R//4tvf/gP4/kvx/YPp7@/8@ezv7/1o/hfj/exP7ob56b@D7//CcUnYn/4r7ofPKfh/xeF@@w8@/u7/xv//Uvyh848@/u5f4I94@e/@4C//08ff@D@KxfJf/uuPP/7pxx/97OOPfuPjj37y8Uf/tPjx9/@1Voj@/Alw2t/@2c/x/2d/9rf//uf4/z//j3/7Z//93/7W/0SOP@SO/@tf/lv@@ze/8eO/@dG/@Jvf@HbO74/v/P32Af7f/hp8Hp7Ph@B5SLk@1efb75SfX4YaYSrAA3QyOCuCTvV0ZLAqixVYQfxAg/m9f/bx938T@PB3ARLe/lt4g3/@AkE/oZevvhoLy5DRrGa@@grU1K@ENfJVFOgnjH3Ig/pXePIBAL6iUP5hARQk@j8gFIAxASXBxhInEFyix71/8e2/@GP0D2Ki729G8RWkbwR2CYE/yCL@BBteUIwo7E@w6X78@Q8//vE//fjzP/z4899Cca2urGc3s6p2z0gdAJYeAIeAqw@BA0ANzREwGRdjRXAsbuDIUkzLvHkDlbAILjBO0rHSMrwlzs/r9bPTfP0sf1bnn3N4z@Xr6JPLn4GjDs/z09MG@wzsT/w@eZJmn6kqf4Z@Ma1OeCGDGei6NDBW05ShYQaHheA7jK2swxsOGGWgx83woAwEPc3gtaqZ2LAGYQSK97EydNbLOL6Edm8N8GIkHifbKIMmz4ZPCQvErGWOWCNdG/KIGfSoEwaGGUKvo7hWjGfKtW1IsDbcZogLkWdib@D5plYv14Z1RPcNZQFwZJ5CkgCF171mhvVv4L1GOAE@Ntz@BrJSrmUy9TL41KiolFq2QWlqJSoclT3DqNzozxgOmz5@wthnca0c54Y5VAsT0PibCaEf0/jUYwg/y6RFcehfOumbxvhQ50OiD/fj4Y/Rm@ILAMCrqrhSC75QjQDwBIKHHFWGkoVHhmMAymXEyF7gQfpIJpah@s3QC6QPefiUzwbvlBEdFmdpaQlcG/X4cvwA7CfmXlY8X3dxLokUwwqLr67H0RsXvojlfEuHZGelt9Pwq8H/ziItYeVESceWkmh6J5lMSc0sOytOgsogC0glSlP@MwQXS4T@XLWnaUHQyVeYEkvRrSgK0qBl9PvwfO5dPHWGoH5n4/GstspH@xVu4Me@diqV2jfayloMnvQ@wAtZxNUgUBl4wWoO2yuStX6j0lACOkHTW43V62Jqk2mx@vHOCUQ4OWBasZBjoLPfrKwVV0orpeLy6mppraitrK6vrJbKyyD4VgulYlFbX1lZL6@v3VKWnoDsyFbSzdJG/Z9Mff6rfzLrM9sXP7H6V2yYY@ptrD5U1XyRclzTSmvVUQ3yQV6xOg18cOtkdKPicsrYGS3fusFJY8hW7EZFZl2AD4stxNgCeMEH0OKkDhPT8HsHVTHliveB8WnXuFYCdlBiZ8AOHJuot3odtHB1b1eu3RRTiqrZznVzdGlXe@AaMnR778u9472DF7ntvWNQjr9mxeVCLsDEB8Jj/alPDFniEUizRxp3llZDZwGdJ7hx9AXkHirYZvu4atN32InDVwc@NVqxDbHlsR6L0ezXKVTXeQxvqTk9j23kg9DZmLa6/F7gLdcBk@G7wzzV7UsetG3yrW5B0DMdj7HzeqbfnQPxst/DzUuG@2vDsNNrQgZxlJsDPIUf13KcWQBr7OXhnFI@Dzai4zQy7UQH8KO9z5@dRJ4nO5tbz2Kr7OnBi@2JR0kAldj@zu5J8LrGQ2XUUoDi6539/clX8UCzb5GV1rJZkL/wg88sfeiZW3otQbTcHfd/LIG1bg8YWKcN3DJRe2qCWNw4ZYnzenl5Za20tlpY19ZLDDpEKPOIvUzoF8ZSh@m@/nhVzVc7h/tAiG8yLwa9qmvg7fEgynAB27rGN2KYXuwZGJk9vLoFr2nyY7gjro0XjeLAQBNv/Bz02VxPeKAXOl3zogsi9NqRALGmrjP4fuoH4hvRj3@3h8/TIL@pEGsGOM6amh1WiOVoQLG4Xi6V15eL5Wx5vbxS0lZLpaxWzGpr5bX1QlYraGVttVxa17LllfXlFRC2EFpaX4slQCiZnXwe@hItHqenabfwCOsNPAvcyXXrsQQfj2HsfUoHfUFhCT3RCHwHLG5AxDhefuP5tEY3bdbieEt8Ae9gB7Q6a7HE7u5WYXc3Hn@KLzh4ulWIx9v4UioXCmtP43GDQragVyjG4w6PA0EA5vOXQuHpVjw@4Ahw/3w83sWXnVVUiuNxE1@2Nnd3MZ23@FLE@AB2yUP4iyVf1gDMxpflZdKq4/F3ATqA2@QJrVBOd/AF08SQXR6yBWHx@OcyP4UCYDjicBzDM1nWzc14fI@/bG5iyBdU8BLP6vfwZZM@8bgLL8CJ8fgFOC5cw7Dj8SY4kR/j8Ra4WiMd/PDQcNxobft6PD7iBEISxeNDgtZbl3HQ2IQ/JvPs2TO967eNC/4ZufzZgqxBiDkc7Ow2P/@8eXHRdEebO58fYcgXXzzT344GbvOiKaI1G/BxIA6EXPZGkx/I416joVszQ74HIfZESGPUMDBvDf0d5El8LjCRXuMLCPkCQoYzPhwbfHoA2sTP0x48n@pNCpEfCqHnsNmMV5FR/VHfwHErbDh0HXG2p7dcp4rvw9piMpXMjk5XC@dV8ma9lHJTqN5iaCdFF4ihOGTKzeh0WCucg9RaK8pV/qn42bBYMuPZxd5jEGmVRf2xVlzJDCuL6feps2xDeVzUyhU8B9HpJFlS1R6vrr1OD@LxCv48Xl6rvE8VkgXG4CernK6dP14rVeJnjx@r8VMNXtYyer5YWVtTqrdQeB96oObANxqNFEtdG/qlomD@UAOhjOJIvHLDb1weUfHMaic1zA5rPAdspFSHNQ2Eqj@ALqgwiTTVxj3lA7wTh2O@AFIMHxcqOF6Yimvr5ThkJJ9XNlAaofyA5xsxIRDMDLx6NcPJPzlWUfnFXlp5VcnhSvGG02nQNSPsTRQS1c5XuKGDNnPKxVekd3uV2AnqpnSnNcPzKpp4lSBtUwbThx@cw/gogba2HovVhbKGu81zu3jdqePm8HJDvxoN4ZuipdeJMfRzzwxcNdWSflt8J2VuZ4jXOZuOLQOOR6Ao9HJ7B7mXtqd3jOqN@kq9pd3TuCcT995DH6jX6uDS2ylKm@nKNRWjUa/XGrWe0ev7IzB6SOOuB3GhE2RPGYfE3R1ygXuj9hRKV6jaeNaMga9Lw8QwVm/jlvqntac3g0oFYG@rRo2ucY0n4tXOY7s2oAweGi7uxdg7gG7XwE0Pre6bsx2E2wJC3tyqdZdB6WQm9jxOnGB5PeXnBvMjAhq1wm31onaK/h/wZ0ONx89V9fTDOejhtUJ1lNBr3qDJ714qNMFQWK0OwU9bW6laQBq@AWaJViLq1S5r1pqvh1W31geVuErgHyzoBhu5BjTA02KxmC0W1rNFDTo76AQhGL5r8L4CXw2@EK6tnS8upqxUnLF4tjAs5LSsZmhZ39mxgaiFSgVpC5VCr/DUlUwxbaXaDtM3VKojaINVzACIgC7rm9luCmIdGbrFwZXMO1BYcMS/@g4o4C6l2rmnyuOVajv1lDUU8IAOG75FtrpSjdZoSql2aqnXSjW1qNQ84x23R6iA/UUgJbdMlrxB77SwuKplb9SGemvpnr@krRUrp4OlU1WDshU@XGzEf1CPnwOhb2NgxERnBUAVqIKfbKZceQi7/9CvXwWtzjKgWrT1YlWAxPpCZgD1UnjvJ1@Xl0om14rJpJKsAtQieJPsUW5IQCRBbCUfaY/joH7EK/H1IoSHomYqB9z6WtViidtY2/T6bGU9lriJ3d7cbkTXgn2PjUZ6RpWvjxi7yIBBnqfpzFwjwRbJpebqNBqxWdu8ONqsCujNLW4xRVZwxNiZ2MGo5hc/dQ41s1F/zZ9nOLMPqYLq2XSsU3YuZnqLy1DmduQdyufdxDhR@Zx4fiNTz5/F4nFsk2KOLFUuKcK4@yZB5wmzrRt5NXPlOdqYLKVXeGs7PVe@eWFaN@Vltc6XJ7LENxkgCS4Fque/SQB/3d4SqcVCnFjCduSaHDAFfRBuIM9LpTiOBhisf7z@eu11@fXzlwcvD3bZk0KlXClHlfqzJ9msltSSG@wJ6JHm0Q7k9QNzSto39hfVRKWfXF5JLk/bAme1xLC2EpRRq9dVbaPIHgNzsgoIk462qhY@1Dmn1SlgtQghH3/zD1aGG2V4L4KaVgEqljLFel1LF5mS@Pjtv8HdxcU16dJW1xLnCZ7EypoCbprLKmqJel54a2uakvBU/gaplxLeh0SxUE5sHYgpyvgqECOxnoglys/ffAB7BUyQevviwiySKz@@Bmip8o26Af/sGxwW@UZdfAPywPOW8jgxto7A0thP1@v1NK2USdYzuNOqWKIB59Pb6jm32FG/T9v0Z3hp/DNeBx5pz4N3@Qav6Q2DleoaA4Mgn//4m79fLK7@3//xd86UD40Pje@DWFxfX1/Viom/m/7k0wsxll7YZEl@wh7vU/Gg3WAXWnLs@k8ceUovqNvHB1vf2znBTtWwddyEt3XwIodBePN8uI2wZRm6a43E1fMjhMK@@GTrkDkue7l9SHFe0QZS8qUBJpHK0l67Iu75yl4xLbeM87WlfGElr5UYqFCFtUpxlekgpjw8MEK4ljAqo2JtOf0RN@ZSWwpFXthEGAzbN8Gs9owK@/xwn2KQGEgvbO88P2AHL/a/zklf7n/ybO@YHR/snrzaPNqBcjzfOWbxzWO2dxxnr/ZOnh28PGGbL75mEHy0@eJkb@cYEeRjKOJQ0eQECywrtuGNvDxqoR6ZV2PentO6NPxxf93t63k8TXrc28Z7qAy8tmXcf2CbYLtFLbfjzQWuyDFEr7fbbgx3rpottoD22kIaVALcONsteGusNPjqfcEtLbLWyovkGmsVXtjLG2vMKog/Zq30lo/Y4uLimR0P@odoMQLDMeqFmzTAL8zT3g92FlKrKywNhmJxRQlDXhwcLhTk28Kro5MFLQg72l4oBi97uwvLwcsOvK0Eb7uvthdKwdvTze8trIbRXmwtrAVv2ztbC@XgDZh0YT3E@WJ7QSvEJLGuQGtboHtgU7t7@zssDUBKdSwUh/3QMeENhEiBpsWPEUGSs3T6uutkyQZpjiag28Z90BJ8DGoBdb1TpOt5lqWdPvyAFgnAEC0WGAW6e9HKCqx4shp0HrGb2AIWaAELBPALuIEd4dhijRUVBsELHW7hpPhhm1kWf@nRNtXPPLaB@nodmCFLR7XRdmWIYYhbrGMLtwJlqkNDox1aBk@gGuQ07sYVBfc4vni5v88T65OKmooTJOP66gycTh@wQRHhF4sOvrxyeLVQXSCtFoTSgTdtx27HajM2WZtICijnwkILEIxT90q3sgyVriwuaUC8@MK3rwAwBIO7AC6@uTOVamFZLwy/RRlSkJg7B7u8hLgoosbGa1lhmChRioL5xpgPH5h8O/PHX93xVzvJcQvkPFscH89pDWEV9FuQu2oJgk4QoJgLyDGZDMSG4lBYpFwLQHT48gMHZC7rkFAhyR49onxswNt6kpLAeBlKkakIgggEwYh8iCzI2iJlV1nIp2mfFq5AogOBsR/hBzk3R8FhKSBZJzM6UatBKwyqc8EGU7Y6IZBFUKeNdQ3u5WID3lE8AidnWROaSZbJQG0VA9G8yzIjyzrgPSFTG6YNnGu4oUyUrACNkWr/xTavIX4yEPlzDyoxyL0KVRgIi0fYfInRFxaaLpj2VQkF8pCggG@RaVJICA53d7yjbYqW5u0F2RJjPyTm3m5F8hGPDewgOI3Iioc5cF4RxSXPegg0hV8gw/ZbA/ScJTmyTEZABFwmwHbG4VSVw91KvrynEDuTpVj85FKgWJ5bip0HFuOXKwV0ayGLQClAxKcAbwag6We8NouzUEBfSCioNN8NBXSgIS9BGx9D8ID40OWG8dVPjw@ddGWyKUO7hRrkUoFHGX9tjb@2x1@x@YKPzjY2WHEFTJkmurRVcOGmflYGR5vLyvGInfFXGv2pMUPG6QQSmKcAPIeikoMhA04LY5QgOQ9vqNF7eGdajW3uNvZe7JyMhyK@nNcQGe/6jm1RGso4mMgQhnspfFGCHKU6SASub6YOeRpZomfj@ORoZ/N5FvKnsI2wBUzqAPAjWsJYCW5lCuBrGy3oj9tZljreZGmFPcKcZZkYS8CXBydhOZ4BqOam2B70i5RUgYME7@MtKYEtMjYjqXiKpRT24ewMutTCGtN6/Q/LvWV7bbnNRstrqOxyPIEOIqS8FDAveNPkygZCtvmZopWZib0tFNiKu8x8owsa97DgTuOnct1i30bdotxF3XfIKPOqDM8VRNkiDmqBfnFctblbi6S@EfkAfbEZgx925zRimCH9HNmTQqWCxfPSNj41L/dptON5UXleNijR6TwI6zV2Eh0Kxnk/cTLFoGmZaIfSvcRsDwfER/KgoizrOVBpJrpaTp@eONokBr3hzXMs@KWTtXBmlg5xNoZ9yzHxDDg8jwbnzt3wtNVc7MBmPbBzadCXD1CbeIyb2NtNR9jw0/Job2lsodUau5E6clH1G7CS@vaFCtzdMS@YqrY6ln7hgcNqk@tN7Dg4xwNTsEwdKEhJaPsNXSuUhL1Nh9Ni5vCu58MXnzM86RNtezmIpFumP6J1uKhk0VpcAw/D9cwrA8QOnnhktHMxbsY@yLSL@uGw1Lgf7a@dMHh1zzPcCau2zyNK9smnn@AK5yfpvOAb3C3b0N2m6eN9Cw0@TtzgKUpFvj9uUNFiDMF1uACDsx3tTOfOnj7Et4lYSDEaGQtnNtFIgBT1niFNqHS6TyhJmWT8JYI53Z@P2@xd/KpQj@Fum8YYXgdoNQBaUSubEkSfeWS5BUAgd0gC7Xy1d9IQx2Jxu2lsbmmOGRmhclW@9au8BJH8i5xP25ooNiH7eLYGP94SinrlcF6OkzGHNh/UNvxHTEi6WAizjtj61MWerpxzs6hA9ogkeBDnEeeER5FcPQoJuiB6iYAHHhiPW50cZLq8iLjjGgYBkIkqh8MnLJhfMe/NqZmmpduX6Kpy@5@lPbcVqSw68CdSDrQDg7IIo5DPKkK5IWpg24cZjbtBtRCAsPJlNb@0sTnTICLG4TUcJI0qOaYhDivp4TmqrVQYnJZ6BC@bIlPi8BNJHQzopnvQ1Rx3xBPCwwpS1SqAoPJBMsGwpQkeKXUtpAaiI00lkgvg26r0wpVfRpjPLLs7tzypRWIHUmtmZ5VrOAh1GmTrnCc1XxYCvZVoYcaihsSRehE4oWv3QRO3jI7gOOjGiEe4yT1FFa6@BlzEOJ1OC@fwzx5HXyp8NAIblIFDQChCFGzGeMTBROaCTCNoPWg6mFTIelRROCyFVWgSLzITNAb0Z2YmM1ZPEeSnJtJNYxmidmpGKIihoESC9IL2BEOKPtQGH19gHa6WclrHJkgEFgQO0Mhcw2vAjYdyBhtYIrjaBRmccyZvy4KgVfkuG2HgppCQKIFUvZ0eIKTpe8N3neu@OTSsFAjMBh731WfgJfSwfp87CCLQycAbK5vyLuTV4mIKYp0SXL58zh6xlLaxkVpTU@T1WVlRgsYoohcj0SORQUjX6yxVTKeWZeQVjAwol8cRrMxGUOQIVtIpTSIoCgRaCTBwFYOQfAYmGXHtOOJyBHGA93wcBg8Nm5F6upjRzjc2ymi4RjwnIhdnZz29nClCZI56ITMewtHygIj/@XiJAPlyMdKPRFCsZJYBBU86Mx4QpjoRECQaTXPlfGbn9CtTXuTgs@x8KDqeXWy4p2UsL3IqH2nrM3D3fVd44vmRfTpFMvTjLJ1GNgcdgZokpNY1cCYoy08RFZ0W0K860StGRnwJAsUAEUHiMbPs7V19XfPTOzsE7tAJMLzMYK5mWRnMEJAoIDHKEBlECNHAvGi0ev0ADrrissKHsXgHRom8cPBU6CvQ7tuk9suUSIxx8uGBUIBPnOJIfQinbwoiNPb3nuLjy50jHAbYe/E5VOECliPLwl9ZzEWOMSjilm7zewJM34QsgGzjBo0oK6@q8fTRU6YvsEnkAn4SO49IpUMIxiML7ZD4wvQbpiOwcVJKPjJ8oiMddBgAlJUq2Bns2mC6heQY8QPay/w8RJrJo9hEKnAEEUUGkUJIs5OjzRfHuwdHz4lyh43N/cNnm4gZDMyW7rYBfb@rYwOxbcPinWpAzxh2vxd4ZwiWSW/KE774bSoIy49@5cQDwAaFNMh3MkdYXs70U/Dce1YEkigBNCgVjbbRn4EbDfIATBTGm4GQ1yLPtegKRZ5m9YTU4U33hFKO1lHSES0dw7OTPjC2T8eu2Vye5CW@p2Bl0vGv1HJRj7ogfnH5eZfLRToEH/nIG/RxRMxox6Pk11stw6MlYyH1AaVhdSgRIVkihAKf2aUP5QcfcA/6XoGDzgCmTrcQ6L2hmjuuLIL2yGn3nXTciILEsUgd6UaqlaQWiZT5mfxjqqM5rjLOS4yn9pan9hZS4wKXvZ1UyMzz07djitgs8piSPG@5biw1M66eBONjVHMdaPReF1dy01gIlzpUYVhNtI7RGY3Jukeyyh7JVhy2xNnK3d1KmSDsuEYmOpyw/xQGc7sNZEtNjW3QcDxZXwMX65@/2MY1vlBPyWdvpIlB8MQpDVCnJZwUnzgxNJczEBNIQ5oCOBXJnVOnEuBLCYRMlflRIroGTS2LUQHTBmkRzriJspIq6XjCUIx4olgVvbDblo2cIMPOzG1PzlIhEPryWdRwqJXPTfKEyuik84NrhBo5JNRZKYDrqqoKERQ@rkE6DYhbLANlz/RnF6M8XQxROKmTmXxYH0WdcGtcFCDoB7B7wFcmXp1Z7kg55AwfRlYiBStUxbCwXKbw8pAta8vLkTUNB69esNXVcMkDbgVhK8VCuI4CN4Ww1fXYdxonC8cTOD9iwxEVimyFPIOmO@iChmVBI@aPtoldP@aNm8VD/hhVA@UqzS1YT4hj0TV4rIc3kzQNvIEDL4n2mTbUcrEFEIonkbtdZOcNgBcD3dVt3@ATxyjIPWfgtgxKkCLSxUeux@99oZtPQOLTHXrewDX4ADD4tJ0WXZ2COCge1PSgR4t9s6gwXBkurm0yfbF6aYFkjmAHLhrqnAmkpxQOdckbnIRCJFCLxkEWTkbqlpF6fOhFuIqkrpzsFyiXJ/sadWnylHTMAJFXsArRmLtjC4LAU90M2eNpcVqnbJIBcCj6Zw0NTncy3DiVdrhAw/uYacvfPJ8xGEPc1Yr2QUOkmERFZTpX5MQeSQA5r9OS4xAciB7Dc@qeCBe3RpGCeG@KycfCGckI0iKol6IuxUWu01uXcoMQBS8E90QQP9eg9SngQYmJWcBgzldAIMsrHEJM@E5CYPvkEMMoDsgFb6hpsdyQIBBHMImH4ps4RFrh6FaEXYAIuF1LahfPP59om10K0UYpUT7PNplTClIibXk2GC@yAMPSRcAgUySP0sEaSg728jCczJOAlHsakLor82OpPTTzIrkpoDFKPDDrASFuxVjdLKQQuedc8fuhxMSZVDMj9cOVJKhEwQjEs9TuxVCFoIGUCjx3zUgMrjPLOFKSUIhYyTAtcgRU4EgX5RoHKdCDYc5wscKsgnJOlkWVxaQapLsaLLNPXeN4WUWziJZV1aYLuxYprFw6MVZYEUmWc3rRmg2ODt7GRYvKsEOJi@UY8c/aWfZZGydDhE@0j5LUmCX/xhdwRBrk61rYIoPyBXmllQDBC2@rYu4QRXuU3zEe4i3IRo6H9VMXoCG4Y1flpSQ81sKCUGdA6RmLV1TEsHPAzhJFpwPyGhfD0ebf/aLEFHIMYamxbzge6oLoaq8IsAT7QHIeM6AEsHhhSRQ2wkVCMo81UskdGJDJiP6sNjYaHK4KmcuIUSxCdkbWXdwZn2TKdC5GGMa7ydk4ZBTR3YftvxrNyGhuRpAcNEck@rpgzoiv87r9ZWdGQ92tLzQ30Lv6Rfh5JxQxob@VClIPSPVDfSGwDrg9ENUNhKItlUEc2MIb9FJ9vt4jyyD1ufDhssl3fIKv1XUxJi1rjEaj9XNRgcRzWIyYRf2IETOdTaodomif18l4vqkiaSAkwM6L8ah/isjyRRWnAbkzo02Vagwdo5UbNBpX5SsaSZXFgyHITo0uacSKT2PhccoytLP6uOJBrnYgFGavbxn8Pj9tv7F5sBfe7ihuNzE8B728nONe5K/NSzPPAWPHYi0@3uQO7RxX3vOQxs5L6MpwFb2fY8cGX6xgiFv83pA5aQyUNxgJl/XbANzpgMZr42U78vIngcDLRTMLwbrHbwwdOU4zzL2ON9WCTcozkKW8e5D5CyDMoElXsbR03zNGRh4j5psW/PR03IKfB5M8jyXMH9jGPsQ@xrsSc2/1Kz22HckYXX80kSptoImpOHZEIXhVLV89gmMIPl1w0nSgbqDlGrRSQhgJtOXOsa0Rs3FdE7/SndGR//KOR7wkEC@7EZM6tOSB3624UlhfJWHviR6O4mH/nctBWEmJ8bPhK0xcQFgFbkZbh0cfW9MysSaDN8zxRRTczh/3a@GOg/vXaQRLPPL5SFzHfsi6j1lrPGhTA5B93sqPfB6HR/sWXhB4rdPhB2xrZa2wWmH8JlJiQ2wtdINDqLEbwz6esI4LA7Afl3Et48qw2DJW45emNwDAY38ARYol@q5@0dMlYGq5wjCZyMYDsq/HlimFQY5jjft0dOwwQoua7nRiWoiN7oETvQoSU3iLfsFQQGrBz2PWaNiO02cVcLTxAkbqDPBKDRkDz3/Xs02MoCv1VFN5DM8KPCHrtN0e2jE2/lqwKB/XEzkmO4Vmfs7kBEW8GqNSQNOv8dxXZXzsORAsMqMDHTaf1YAeIc0awhjlowQAjX1YisN5fNyTJs8lSNvZO8BRG0oQWmw/FYRgEfkmLKU6d01JmkXWlIBIwEX0yJi0rj@flyMjyU08K1@@PE3yUBo1SnF3OETEe710QA65fqHDV59s0EYHRhsXiZwKtkCKrFXZrQTENSCo4eDKEjUpVw6ghuni3Ey4IgVIH5dW2F1oIxlYvgeSKg7ZDPulSDEoUZp0vA3WrUwGa@dyDgv8a4WqpAa/WiOo/3Ay6xGvzQUq@CJd1HEjbqZNxVt8IoZmScQE01hesfMSPELcwXGJLj7F@YE8xrlBjCbSoGk2GFDlGeVjriAsUOdUqUvJsiG7wNF3bj5l2Ui84iEfMb6bv5Ad1bRqsOXfsAe9GzRGsjzKoJ9F4FtmgLSvxvBXWHQuTzxo3dBLkFhHQU6Xw5HXqfTHoY2bQpZpt1VKuUXHWnIRD3rENO/PXIt1ZiO@yimYIvR/zruJymfteJanh1MG5NCko3ieDVPjRAxyPRw5l6lhdgSig6WGtLqTrA50i8F5eh1FgmjhpZinEQIGx2EbOs47NpB2KbmtgjWGNTCQGqMajuHxTQ2o8PJmQatiEb7CAFBVERAsVCaVXQonMoPoG2YyGA5G3Xj4oF9BK1vGnwrH2iP8PH4U/22484fo0BhmGyNFrkuBGI1RmkgQLE@5nSouZe@XKO9UfifKO0WPoLxz6BGUd5qe36m8wYjxV1QQ6GLogTYOmuyPwaLGq3mkJx@neMzQsxD2UNtfT8Ye9PEkuInYdPjOdGyn33c8PARidg54mjMyQeERf0jzMU@jAm4wkPN8@EgrF6Dp4VEqXow3cddBfTFFbjxjmPdfoE9afGxb9NHkgZjXaUQ/eFUn3iEBRXQlUS8pEoPyYVJcpnJ1AtS2S1pfXGORpKpBxqmg3AZjFDkovcL4awRHpOi0fBFyI6MgoRQ2K8oA9Q6MNxkF/WZHEVQX8nE8FlKdzYwlKxFji9WVUhMisRPf41ZSqHXHI3NNDZLOwK4RfSKwY4Px3mFGMjivDBrpTWZkLw2m2B6/tntLXG97KEan8H5aupDbdQYXXYar31EH5DfIYoSOg9o9apeg1ePB0gNgn3ZFLotLhcUPxo/z7GWfgZG/J@9Nf37ItlDxb9LF53wsIBXpJsQKq4UFqTsthEPaCyTpA@BzPtDHRxzC5KnOIhnYRn6ALDzHkThI/ojYaUbCshNTtUADieu@jyeQoGYtrn7H4ofR@jgNE0ZEDUBuXCBlZSEAnZ1ZzsaR3FLuotndB1aZldvCzEzSnoTJTDYNHOor3JE5Poo4OXYD2cHUMTfbxq@h/oJU@ew12P33sCYkKrkyyy@hByO3RTfUt3Fvfg/PS8c7ezmnggUOKF/g7bqWNcrOxHyN43HUuvRrsL3IVEa4TE5kpwv27BUuNJoZm2bcujpUFW0dQESQA1Kt5G2GiIduu2bPyRwNInMD2CNVDjfT8mw4LZxllpGnKYEHIhptD1VWHXmF8pnC7Q2iucpZwraJt6dhyQPRK7ND49FkLXbNFt@VsXWIWXGNdwPT5cY25iYHdUnrfoAVtroG3jUKsHguXIhdNW0VyGb7qtNh3ruB7hr8vvpM0osJGc97miOxEmdSjxICqjoGTJxXm1ZCIsCofuL@tgm2kuN1OFQjZR4t1sFzi5KeODVIjBkhbaNjPzhqkmMgr4IBGeieLS6LgUKEJ2J@Z1lnYKEsdvo5DENJOF7Y6Bsqls3FGt@ZNVbMyMsYEBes46ERjGIZihtgSFE3LnpiLmnuB1@fgsak5gCrHDqwsSL0DYgGpByj29j0Dm0KCscvIJjGz1PIb56E6eBaC9cQJgTGKShZSmQaLXXF01htx1ajmDnYNGKAQzDlofVX@3uqP4YKkI2yBwRMv4/Xn8o7yCnrwvqElk6lREYWRQE50BtYvm4bzsCzRr9uRogt0GHKQncGrxG9fi1ex9VxNMO4dZbHE07YXv6Alrvh2gQ01EF4F/crGBI/EaIGK67niH6WWWIbjJeVp5vhNFHqBMP2RRh2jnJNwEQI9E4MR3pwmYBPe7yyfNkAiE7aLmb7OYonF9jpLX9AQrTr4OIKfjNtFpc69ECMgD9VCQpsLAsid/qGyxMDbhs5Ayb7Z9@J7F8EARluIDQhUdH1EX6UzVgs5HvekQAexB1Bxe/qjsQB8QsZB/DwhnjevTUNMUaBnRuf3aKbViEFShaeiNvke@DCBL9zanwWDsd8MUnEPRGvkIvT0TCRUTK@zj61KOx7RRr6E@ufSGWWY10SljOUWNuPMwm0qmJ6WE4asGaVFlqkzBqu1NjAHRbQLgH01DxfrOFcC1@1QWNnWIvXwCCG7ra6UCSoLxMZxneJTm2zTWQDGw6HvYPzGTwG6PH8NoUr0Pag1zTw4g@iV7BNk@Y9cJAcQFIhaoVSDrdemiThzAzw8xku9aTx47YStC2eFNklaPwAYDCOhD2oyBONXwrC4Hu4simgTiclXnEopIhkwfdT4alq5/KQjamg4rk8jiMw@YrVSYzaHRiVcPBsYksYDnj5kSVO1457yWeOcNiNJL@vmzTujXOBfMEyRpIjejjJ74VhfCZDDs6FZzVRe8aOpav79w/ySm7yQShafEMP3zgVEpjP4VXDRcvBauQC5y0QYS0@ApUXQbgyisflM5dcsAfMI@dc@Rgi3xtUiG7dErSuRZsCr2sxlMn3tblWR2hXY7whIAVHILTMOQ6/iyFJmYZKaAiKZ57bOJT5TE2CVcV2JzXqc4vmP8@nJJ/gFcOuF2Rr5PxRq3HuCNMIFgm3Ikt103J7A19PNkZ@OtC8FpxK893oRhKDD6dW2VCs76KdVkO@wmthwv5mvMSnqJIuLIw@hTpEi2CZeDgmHyduFs2A7I5gMWCR88aElScFY4c3/RlbVcQiT36GC3TvDE@IEds34DU6GO75SjBdLxqo5@c8n3gn0tOrXPoAf89qd7rlOdBJck3NGolW79F84afNxMgWyJMX7a456GBWcKYf4oQbVKZ3pyx2ApFDS3P5hD@nFIHTusMB4uDtX4msFpSnhPBdKwBFW1bEDL@IeCrHxBG9WEbdEWNkvAQs3RDJijKI/FAhaMJ7Lzx6jqyqz13jAh5HJuao7SVRXwpmvnOxbT6YeHiw9@Jk56hxtPPlztHxDsWkhfzBhuJBP08jZd41nlhgC7xJL3rWXS72yjWhH8cehw6PQwv8uOX4PtsFc9cAc/xSh5j6wIjNnXMv7s8Pe@kZboXHP@HKPG2@p5XGnolbhAa4VAnKd80NcD49nPIUzvzQB@IOfzT6USOWh93FUGaCMOchKD@xJTUdOpOVIMTOBuxSnI5/jRqgsCbG55iDu7hyYo2thMYhh/C8hOBABFQAIBxX3Y5ydHlEtK0C4Q3QOVGNxLzyY9vB9t4qsEOe7DYly7Z5uVCH1C3HvoiJ0xMiOSDNDTqtLF5NUZEkpk1BkASuW4CmQ5TmJeIFyqN9kNdyhfyv7kiDcBL7H@i0gu@wJf877vOe3qc/81C4Wdv25cEmER3ndmIP3dhZcDN30M0@gm58Q91EQkWR0HfbTj5/N7lAv/wPvIN8zgZykbuVv59N47/a/dwP3mb9S5@x8Pe/DWcmA4/typHsO3OJ6e2vbsPO/1d2jXzadpH7dlH849aJ2VsnxCmRn7J5IplO0upj1Dz2DviAPQ41BcM/nlzdLc5om9DJpNQaW2gbHMs1vmg@PGRLrER@2CL6sRX0Y8vKf23L4eeXdcZegLC4s5cdf0KpI5sjxgpa@KSV8MHpY/cscY@u1r8dy79MN7psH5e0uyPUPcOBNGxzIrvjS6RJ2nz4wMaWgfOdLnyNL7G/WGEebG8R696jg3FyMbroO@SYGY85sfydDwrOiB2cXOmLg//4mYHj52YKbo3uSRRwherYgnhhRykS1@00/SaWrYcUDAdL6RCx6CC@yGsqjbTB0/Wob8C9B8pkHY2hDAdj56EcrxpZF/MSEw1tak9IMAP//5fdVgEL8g0e/7jJ6h9wk9U/7hr5x10j/7hr5K5dI4nF/MBz803TzoNqZjH1OsZvagc2Za@ebZ6wk2c7bPfl1vfY1wcv2avNFyd4aefhy6f7e1sMvjsvjndYcMsofb40XFxyz6Dqt42WQaPzxUJhhd8BP3Xrwgo71nvsmdMyroB5Njy996TLX3K24dd5rJ0rwx05fDqoj4tZfLFrgsaK@FyTHHHCHddN4OQeziPKszwxj3SapycvBITGRnc8BBu4@dwe6SC0joumlYJNGwDvgC@g0fmULK2dxql1UlraOXHFffj5ZAqCUvj8mG2@2Mbji7f3TvYOXhyz3YMjeD38Go/ZYdt7eGzM05cYRIDPD7b3dve2NsmDZ6CQYzi2RhvW78pCDsGJKq3LzqB1metbaBWKt7FrPRKxmO3IXREeSw7s8PieNrAUzrvzw05xwAkYe2nz6PMvUasx3rF4HE/u5beXohSQOxCWCrhpBFITVwNUCYZUS1XjAqk3YksYXKUbVFPkzjKJXKF5YtNg8S0cRsQJaX7RKilsEjUktAi4EZU8CLbG3oKCnEomsxuEsg6p0eiBTA0HVjvyBaM@EQezoh2ZkKe0eoQUT5zds1v8bHDpAXzPV3VTsr7LAXBASHhwAByDQQ9fvzT2cJCElQTEwEfDHzxWucfbXn/3GrVG3OAqPJ6iJkQHQURqkapUZ01XN21ej2Pbmrh00L2WaVIUj@DxkBzLkkOutCQO9H8xx4azsgAZBynYgZYtjYpw2g24AWR7V@/4HkvVFBwNBhPEsE2@UuvC0sHco3FhFzcsXeEyAkq2jDdR18TNTaHCSacLSxOmOWLj@QjibYuO33hoPIj5dCpFXLdHhcYFUzrXdu/NwNOpDHwXNIBIjcoLPFao7/OrRxGN0xGsnPIc4Ei87OmbKDywc3vQMsYiCFsn9dZ8/14RRM6GUSJLfCh3wQq7t4NeHydCrvEMKjrmAowYWinZxdkoXoep8RKEc8M9XAzhYgbf1OpjqUWNB5miWIkjEkV9fk6qTZ02w92bKnE8XxsciK9@cGYUTX97fFseTZM00UwOrDkPz3PGRQx4spOLx7x0GC4sGvmUE9S8KrFYKDu@YV7@9HW5Vt9@eqZ@8yZ7ns9fcLGgt/nkBV@UyKdZyCSH5hGsnaTVgLKlCaQxb9DE2HI9I5eW2MolMlBcuiYo308a1SCMD6tO@@PVdJP@5PnhQ43HUmm/CbHQwOumQumWZacyySzFOWeKQBDKTsgsnqwrfbKEM5DXT/CyDqyFKlDERjlCy2sipeXrayKnXeOEHkiWmNDTeHUH@BV5wYLgKPqkovWRf516WsvUlbyEosYUkDMlRXRWYtYUUSq6qIT6qyl023ejA/n9cHTlO3P3/7T3bMttJNc9C18xGmqFGQEYXEhKJMGhqJW4XqUkUaGoeKsoLIzLgBwJxCCYgQQshVSceyqpVDnerOONL5WLnVTymqTsuCp5yPvuP/gL/Aebc@nu6RnMgFzvlp@iBxHTffqc092nT5/Tl9M8PXwpbA9WYvtSvFVK@bh4WtJwXR3t761Ay5Pbr4UW6l7OR8yT5DI2JelKOMs31qTMX0LxW0t9R2MP0ODcOw7GMVKN2nQ0xAhxFi@KA2tUwNbRxAbRs@MHB0dHhkmPae5AWdB7@OxjX6hBxH1dRjrie8ik7BxlNMl/sfEkU8RTPEmyqwZzZuPlqAphg5RFeyhlEb/rPfBn4nYEzyxkQuDFa1aIsuWS3F1IHRSeCMSLEzwJZcSdplWwkFnNNZ58OMg@KZm43cpsG4ev/LEyZryZCNZFS9WTuY5IGsI4HXROcec7u/@@yfbxjqTDBpb3u1OqMB7C72G8fOMZEB7jTrGT7MEV3SK7lM6skJSuybaja3lJC/urC5R6YGIhbGFNrQvjWLDG9vENaebQsiZOA7jPPxeZvXOx3ilVPKXs6h1qx5OelZyCwMgEN9jY16UCircWYgqj1lDzpKsMcn2s3SBuTiSXLTxjJHA384HeAQt@83ZaPaRJgbZdSary9ZDiWSJBSbZ5ZmVkJmC@vbm5fhnudC1k8cpXxc1zSFp/Rufj1x0NZTgP6agQSO7DJ2WZHwvAiqZzwQvsW3LApAqCqZMxpyTqTpORzh/wwg9OAzOHz4/LuF6UpmobsxRv2dh5RtKxE8hSHbQhrCrKo2ap9ReryaFCvpTe9S9PjwcbAuF6@OILfnD2KBijqsQXwdscFRVc8p0QT8VFWILfUFeRfjnCHmHaDyN2X09a/M073HhHminuR8ErPNfvilJOOB6CUjJxG8o574wv3uIC11taMuU8vBMgyvplY/8ln1GpcUo/oEMEFNRAMEBcJtNAzb9uq/uFkLeDxwcL/MonAmgbmK5qwOLNogF@zw6uKpRlWonTwD5RSRVOkm9aq/RbnI73EvzxcK7Sq5ze9177GCZbpO4KLG86Y5W2JyCn0A545ktlmAKY1mr9wbxNza6y73I2mDEq6R3BDPiWw0ClXudUPFMlk05E2Wmc1OIk8KRU0pqAwonJj3RZCj3vVZs62eBpARAWy8bIH7YccX7qriV8R1tc4Yi4I6G8N@oXqFNQxGJUckrYx9CyQoRO9v2WQwcohQJCnyzuWB5I@35cQAeGdNCvdflFQsXFiAH8XzAhWNWFFymf7L9ECZ94YW/qGeod@IRUUmCQNXwfyjh8zzg6fHqQRI0ct9FGoVLywB6K4IlgjKojh2wZOjyYRmdtTpSf6dw3HudKFPytgEbBRAPiz3SuJEAoWjgsjYu3/bfGCUzeY9UpVt9uiU6XNVZ1cHrBdBRdvJ29pe6dgaXngAjcNRYOLhLcXWoWMRKFhS3FgfbiOudeG@3KtgyrEFOhFKIyE7E5AnHjOjXm7UVBvuor9Sd0HYxMUtJKK2KUCNQEAZo8OxNcMAg9aI7emQKZ0F62i698phjDSclxlpJLxh3bFsU9qZKWiV2RSCmPyHZMhCVM4XFCSLFiarbRD4y3/tv4HXQ5qeDUv5X2dlRrY@xm0Y3aFEPDLgFTa2nZvCuh1blfSP5aGnCiB@P74IUYjxgQ0HuaNndZxhNgJN9LYEo5SDAeQEtwNAoSgDxMlgCp/DLGdjaX8dDLKJLNcTwel9nJoRKjyyiSTSVmOtkV8VhP9UYvAOuMHyTBH21wBLX5NbPnQGyWCOcNViNdUIgiuTNtpmnxHzuDhlTTDAHy2JI/662WeF1XL7YSPtkiOgei8lqDoA6icCo4renp9XS6PiUZe1rxNITGVAoYcKZmqsv7giOJJJLe4E0tHlZ0aYv/naCtJaZGUDktDZREKAe0kgTlURPDAiiCkBWHM4sGyiMxCVrKBtWEn@B1rCletdGoQEvZoNr4WMJaycKaBC2lQZf0GinKZNsrg/aWtbrz7Bw7VkenkfJmXm8a8Uwjg1bAGIpgeOiGloDu@6d@dNeIDS365QA/KLQbWyIitkwDB3/zjjJ9qIA0tXUWBNkYIWoLzZbyMwjzcpRuvsWGuTIeE/D4OgPNbzroCUHo3WBwBCbBiDQyhEMjZzFpiulNw6VmkdGky0iGaaxdwOcCrd@TtQt2dxzadzTLpr0wma1mQotCnWSy8I92d2VbOFHQ9o3Mf03BPOEIxkYShxMnrfiXwDGNVCoucZSHQY8XO8uIqymdtRNIb4lHN9M4cDdluS6yIKBpXc4Hbqgs4xjTS8CrKqXjkE7VMo5bV8YhHbZlHJWr80H@VFZd3rkyDnYEs3BUr4wDJXC5Tc21C0Cw4P/NLFFLtAdeixKpnXI3KRoKZyfx1U3XRbqqBt4XJAwJ@FnqK4sPYZjrsj7U3KArtQc6HcvtYfk8kvZgKibNXeMF5jqWtJfGCzu3lMorsNrIaxo3wqgPE4EzGKrxnTH4Uy56apFEIKR1D3RinN7ZBFwk7E1HeB/SACGcwH@7jUez2m1aGXp6dPiNo3uP20/uPUYnao11FC7f4GkZOq5TcxomZPFqS5vOFLkGHrXAahRID2t5xJ9Ac0CzCL0ci6XWLjS4hckGFFJyab3IGXlvjPcgy6GdwTROhHTU2gx0j0U8KKVuVl6bdgypz2CyVsJf2wNOCIblRHBCMFpyQXO2uPyLEZ9QeTF6ETFg1zjhO5lhS@f3BV5c0goaRuX1i@h3vEkXz5JUVNBS7kU8go@@GwWnwiMXYgU9xqB14BfVqvGuDIor7q91hj0MeTsdUODbc3/YOe/2O874bFwYhK4IT2MVByEGuSzgYaqHxwdHz9pP8Z2ug/t0cwL/NSnv@OHjg8Pnx5jzDLLWRfLB0dHhUZsOqB89f3qMEUNTSaYOKLDEYCIhAfTk8P17jzQY/jYFk3whJAR/E/6IUD5lwx@3Z/T/nK55lPkoRJse4aFrKliU0spG5J97wVQ@3obxJ@QEX8abJ7gpA7Tkq8YUkMbC5U@RF8c6XWhQxMdkOo4IlE7AW6mWsJMlGOY8PMUCFIsoBLudTtM7vKKMeXiRLxhbqbJ4QQaLFcT9rkFIowOHybP5qGdJdCKQZ/nCGwEk7jYVp9GgslVc2BhVckyHhtKFi1WYOaoUHLWYXVK0oDiVXtAeMdKXXZsFeeEdoOhGCXVCfDOFCvAOYtMolXz7oqA/ECWyQKvy@1EXhnaHPgkj3q@5pvURhzXlc75AHwVE/RI3cJSM8OdTfVOKBEzsT9FljhO8ea7ajP7KyvIKs6V6xwr58Xl5r9vB0yP3geF7kcWBXihmXyx3YrtLMNDGjHSPJ/MAvdgbExUmgizjYdSEhoomc4NvEIaRai6oeQv/n4nQrj08QGOBwNk6rGlyLoejxEtCYcQA5OaZe@ZOHMaGryWog8MMsatD1LMgPtQhGlkQr3WI9SyIzz5mEH9glUqy8/aMxuYmn2ZO9GdG8X9XxSsVCbsrj0LHhQGfXlzOxozkgHEI6JKL10H1ORuQ65zdXslZEvVn/wG4dVyiVIWIMOMr2F6B@fM/MHd4he4KrfS3XENNQaFxIra8@AozrhfeFyIuWRJ3SdPYfrYCm2nKXswu@/1YIj7MEZrPfp6AyRabT2S/G6r95A7XtbhsPb7VkEbwn8sI3C@DoM3l5fiiaKN8gRezGzsKi6xBjIBB1nWQRhoki@TblSRrOr56Jsm6DlK7CsnPfiFoivkrA@JHCoJ0rWjMTND/Tgw0OpoPhbJAQ4bEOzVP413fXPDTJA96sSzwpzF2KtJazffn307zHZfMhP/DTOGkArp8yW7PbPh/vCqO9Vwc32IUlUpuuxUZolTKhfjsJzEf3LzpYbZqkHz@x5eXruWX/v24dDzN78mJm60GiSytAtXxoGQmFT1R2Lj/oAFUSgY32jSqxpw25HAuFhfGkhWoq2xx4yyZ3ZDZ88zsdZWdQr5gA0taSRhfjwyjXX5hkEyj@Dfd8mWDS2buubrVZnOFdGuXjXVxwRzaRtk44iqOZvTspRyOWwknYxm1yLWFsbcokBXczHR@ws6kczbq4AOtYTByxAsgflA9OA9e@jhRTaoY5sJ5GeZ5Q1/FtCYE5Me56L7ewwMVwKoIKsJnv9lvR8BOrzc9nw5xD80VfhUGRqpWMWQcOYKj6XkocOKM@@7UH0INXLTUYhMR3LwxcEmzMJjSVyKfIp1Fdplktcrnxh0KQ0dJxFtv4o8jIuYu@wIY8okMVCDh72qw0oTHC@oXhIhD0bqiPo/8kWdp8PiKq1/WEiguQsnlUk2SjHSbaDjKeALkyfQ8geFC9DidjXE5xwnxxo9VKzew5TyUG2Pi4Qsh6naEHxoNEYOOQssgEnGDaJLE0ihv2NxKhOgpiOd5EmKj3KghoTFmUYgiigytTpZ3BhS2iC61Eg7CpqCpF8AijNGLdt2rQe0gQ/Hlmr/68cd/b9oX1apMozd1/FEHfAZ6kSTGip/HwVP5raFH/0TcVUzh/ocYN6Puez3/vIMv1EQaahCuHMzQgYj5AgQNg1YFQ9A3wamlxYKRBFGwqtV7Dx4Yx@8fHX4Tb0PxIgJJQao4CsGOYZa42alkIl8cDEYQIQnLMI8FYQSSTCxDqVohmKoxhdcZWNoJLGit7/wptRat5Qd40p3HZQohZpsc1AfXCfFsrY5WdYSUYOyH7/wJYw7GfHo2G3EwNoVgws@xB8IvlyKtpXoxRDa9X/7gL4icuFECNh@uq5zrpPOMfso9EQuyJLOVeiu3Vgky1Ai5iC9tou/@lJCF/Ei3VISFa7pWVEiyq/2jvzEIB24@QO9pJY0EntKliD5hRGr3gFouF1/lUnzfY3x9n3YBdETdebKKj2GedCZ4acjSkquXNN8vfyA4Bng/wj2TFTRuJdgtZHbGv@k9S2VFd@T1r4Y/t4d/qCMV11zzMPJElYnn41/Ew1SvJodOZvm@po3OFGuZFf74v7Kkj86Yw@jBCOCMVu@qzLGSw/Nf/bXCPytcm10iML/68ac/ies4y63ZLLc@n8ajabZci1ke79dSKukDnDLM0iy3K36eJJMYuTNX@8xD8LO8dp8lG3uWN@RB9NWgn10y7POQfCKRqAE/u3TI5@H6nsSVOdjT1coZ7rPcYS6x5wz0FP5bOWzCYPxXfTDOVvV87pjPF4u/I@Ro8OHl0aVuqVaFhVMj03bXqNNfjMyLf/fS3OjaD5faYsPFBYsK0KHXlJA9hJrt6iP/Iv2m/ILtmji1LoItyBppVOqCCrgmnWGYQcp1vzZaDWw6cPcyqOz9ekQKi2p15PGl@@m4j14H7d@dk@cxoe0/fDwgWzN@m/oSrG1wV/i2DYUnOCGWW7SDEy6JD6KjmEPS1cAI0H1wN@jvrqpupc4p5G9cS2MZBmwSXaPldHSFch0R4UmU6q1Mp4L91MyB8M9KA7F31WXvChtL1JHiyMY5lyrv7/5EaSTVSkESewpl6XKc/yS6gY4Y0V45RewQNl0@ajfxpRypZKqcAnKn7n/RtUWKXL4tqYHlYf7@n6mJzgvxLGsf6oNXXiniPz6OiQ2TOwNq@pN/EgLLvhWrjFzKfy47PmQNlUccZ7Ir0Mkh89M/MlG0sxuJs5uXO1kCY66PZTx8Yjx/dnBkHD4/fvr8GBdk9MCIygfPd/TY7Wa9TA5scpFgyZdtgpvfYHdWy2Px8st@qWFT9f/yU6w@oy25Zs3UmmlluR8mytVluRVtRF1x5RYS7bNUnhctgDumLWrruluihcCBfjiKcLyGHvwQYLwwwQGfxdzG4s9XpnWvWxBmPFfo@q@zWtpiTP5iAk512AFu3cD@c2v/Lxm/GcmgJas57t65Wbt5jB9qIUN@EuhvWoISK5vNwhdfrBnjeXQWjBqFNUOtvxq0/ooxg3iV82XIa7jhyB@PvYieIjBOvREuQOPjbH6AVgUG6MDY9/D7lUd3gHckcoOXS9svwzYiagtEznhumDf2zULBPx8Hk8j4aOh35W98R/T2hvwK5yGGegg9L@sx6uPJ/GF0OELboYpRDaOAf@vvUmO4pRCaHCD8wJlMR1UKCeGN@rh0TUcFO6@AtTMgB1XrtwGsjdWybNw9Dj0MIWW@mA0GJl2w9ob9Zx42Llp4hop2/hAv85nA/JmJJ8zWjCdB5O3wlWh5z1hF0qAW94yiWDCrDPnNRVrVL2qvceCpNHxvinZPTDy4JNbUKTyP6dAiMZQybVpit/Cc1iAIohheHrcQBXjzJlEC64gP6bDwYtzfuEb4jJeHpz8FEyXDEAnER/wpiMYJRIi4AY1T7kxw4Kh7NWAEzsX6f30HQ3ChPQvm@o48f@zjWeb61g7Gz6aaYINiN4nl2/oW5kz5wXV8FYbvj@v1KLmCEwDkDqHHimAc4AvVQfclHfRAgxo8bJQ/R@ahCdHFsCVDisOONqZ6WvxN1@dw7X0/JAAsWT39yB@LJionRLU7PQ0dHgsU/dwPw6m3eWdrgxiitwckaD/oJUAbVcCM4d@qxNxZdD5UtdiOzsSb2hSj5Vw@uk2RsmBQkpxhLIQOnssDAbxtk@hAUyZqCq1gbZc57cHBe4/uHR88KBuV@iaC8yUSBWtpjcvZJcqnQ5ZCjLAID1@ne3uDhdwKy8X9atEWrO/rzV7SGZYIwNyaoK4dW0WXignrmRGDWuujriqrN5HU@yt4ngqHG7IynWBkYVM2rhz5a2smijTSWkMRTNh1UMYuqKsn8AWKZwkoV1dACwjt1kaXB8P9k@Sau9crFTWmduhXBRRrpbLHd8HM@zBXvjKKR9NRQtsWaex0jCIoOYxow6rtepH0gmM2jTO3@E5YbPZgPlcGwmtral/IZ3hGA@TC4oY7Dt6dy/6zpnJnCRrEPqm3bFskFP/3f4p2cxEf3RtakX2BU9xHrgzb5rBSP@AoV1aRPTYo9pETgaN5n5Rr5EZNVaAb9OcOPRvWv38GjoX1kU5jbNkXdAKp57rr9gWQnIzxrOgYlKF3DBjtJqYNEmnwAW0MNkb1xYsRhq67hft0Hzx@9D50@RHGgAijkw9bt25Uy8UieBO0S@hiNG7jweHjpzjbT2yHZv33YLoW7TLpKCIOLr7j7R7ivmxi1ao4CkFznnqRqH347vy4c/oEzDGr2IEmSBpZHX1nDp@ixfN2ehu5ZrJzwUY6dQnqbOINmrzpvAjd19ap3Yzgz5lOYhNIuI0GYY@gkIuX/FKt7o9gtn7/@PEjt7jbMRCrmzEqiqWuEg4QFBIYC5PID0@IDj55h1IV8d0KEhj4Vyqae8m67FY7e8XmYpHLz6Og0@eoHMVYgPvWtCwkbuIud2lzEkvBfOy5mMBT2zcOjs0ylJ1MPRsT6R2COSktDhjoShosbqgpaAqcP0MY1924eZPSsMg0dN1GrWbjFs4CsNE9TUDLA2vSXEw6bt9SDdkZ@w65t96MaZFx0nAa1c4ofONNwmr9dqO2eeduMEHfvu@FvZshqBC3g8@@@dH8Jl62oy3f02A4uDnwh7iodH3j1tah/@5vf7D97PYDq9f9rbpZNl@G9A7vZKwzMOm8ETv0oGMnPZYuYmIEOHud6rjzKqhu9Gu9rdpW/U7fu7PpbdXWt3qb3vp2d3t7uzfY2Or2t@907mz2ulUM7UhFnHPa4DdZ/JHs4Gpk8wyzrUZtezCo12/f6W9uD7YbtfX1je7WZr@2sTHYqnfW12/3G1vd7e5qqy3mpwAKVupdnDvSGvidfOOusKTbRWn7/wA';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111   xxxxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@"     L         R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af]          ">r"{\       Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn  # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ /                      >/         MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM  #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#  ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  [[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  :1*23!/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100|_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###\>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwv/wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
       program-id.h.procedure
       DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#     >>IF 2>2
pppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $&&1nu le._e lo=Bid  <[ #]>834757609195 =x= Cry U#age$f ata?6-/;fPLesc~+Num;re 8   
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:!*z(\,_)?218:sizeof' '-1?67^*u"":*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0,)[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ;#:p'34'3                  \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint ("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

This answer was created with [the help](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46226534#46226534) of Chance.

GnuCOBOL has two forms of syntax – fixed and free ([link](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html)). 
In the polyglot fixed syntax is used, in which first 6 columns are completely ignored. `*` or `/` in column 7
starts line comment. This polyglot also uses `$` as line comment indicator which is enabled with `-facucomment` option.

GnuCOBOL also has [preprocessor](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#what-preprocessor-directives-are-supported-by-gnucobol).
Preprocessor directives start with `>>` which can be anywhere on the line except first 6 columns. 
Preprocessor supports its own line comments starting with `*>`, they also can be anywhere on the line except first 6 columns.

Polyglot as seen by GnuCOBOL (main code is on lines 127-128):

```cobol
...   $  ...
...   /  ...
...   >>IF 2>2*>  ...
...
...
...   >>END-IF
...    program-id.h.procedure
...    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
...   >>IF 2>2
...
...
...    >>END-IF*>  ...
...   /  ...
```

`program-id.h.procedure` is in lower case to fix Fission (`RO`). `DIVISION.DISPLAY` is not lowercased because of Grass (`v`).

`$` is used on the first line because it is much easier to add than `*` or `/`. First line is now this:

```
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
```

`(` is before `$` to skip it in Agony (`$` is exit in Agony). `$` starts IP in SNUSP, so `\` is added to redirect it down. `\` is exit in axo, so axo is sent down with `%`.
Second `$` skips `\` in Hexagony. `5 5` and `24` are for Cardinal/Trigger/x86. `;` should be at least 3 bytes away from `%` for Cardinal.
Space in `5 5` is for Ropy, also spaces should be placed properly for Trigger. `24` should be multiple of 6 for Hexagony (otherwise `#` will change current IP).
Double space after the string is for Pip.

Old axo code `"r"{\` is kept because Japt breaks without it. New axo code is on line 5: `">r"{\`. Note that axo is in a string mode when it hits `>`.

Alice is also in a string mode when it gets redirected by `\`, so the code is `/ 78"oo@"`. Space after `/` is for Cubically.

Snuspi can step only on places where there are actual characters, so SNUSPs are sent down in column 4. `>` on line 6 compensates `<` in zkl comment `#<<<#`. 
`>` at the start of main SNUSP code sets pointer to empty cell.

Del|m|t was moved to line 2.

Penultimate line:

```cobol
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
```

`//` is for V, double space is for Pip. `>>*` fixes various brainfuck derivatives.

Incident: changed prolog/epilog jumpers to `$?` and `|_`. Moved `|_` closer to the end (`^_` cannot be used there because of Black).

Placed Red next to Rebol, now end of polyglot is hidden inside `{...}` in both of them.

### Golfing

Some Julia golfing by Ørjan Johansen: `1<<2*2>8 ? 225 : 227` → `225+2>>1*2`. Note: `>>` has higher precedence than `+` in Julia.

C compatibles were changed to use `printf` instead of `puts` (except for eC):

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u "e"//"
const char*i=...;//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:!*z(\,_)?218:sizeof' '-1?67^*u"":*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0,)[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
```

C99/C11: `67^'e'` == `38`. C++17/CPY: `77+a/2` == `79` or `197` (`a` == `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(int[60])`).
`"%d"` → `"\x25i"` for Cardinal. `"??-"` → `"\??-"` for Pyth.

Moved BitChanger code to line 10, where `{}` need not to be balanced. `[]` and `>`s are for SMBF.

### Test driver

Code snippet that generates TIO link now copies missing arguments from [answer 190](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162057) instead of 186.
Incident tokenizer now uses Incident interpreter source code to tokenize, which is faster (0.351 s vs 3.728 s).

Comment: Puzzling is on too now.

Answer (score 7):

## 48. [Deadfish~](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish~), 957 bytes

> **Note:** Deadfish~ is not a "programming language" by [our standard definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028/62131). However, the current consensus is that answers can be written in other sorts of computer languages (the unifying question [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/62131) is at +22/-7 in favour of allowing them, and the [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8094/62131) that previously disallowed them is at +22/-14, i.e. less consensus, and not the ⅔ majority that is required to count as a loophole). The language has also been used to answer questions in the past, with the same I/O conventions as used here.
>
> If you disagree as to whether this language is acceptable, please speak up quickly, so as not to retroactively break the chain.

```
#16  "(}23!@)" 3//v\D(@;'[af2.q]GkGGZ'#)"14";n4
#/*` "[!PPP(22)SP(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@ ␉␉␉␉ q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{#z}
#=<xR+++++[D>+++++++L+++<-][xPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52PLEASE,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2DOGIVEUPDOipipsiis{i}ii@O6O4/oh]>+.---.>][
#Rx%>~~~+ +~*ttt*.x
#D>xU/-<+++Lnd
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[kGkGx/0l0v01k1k(x0l0ix0jx0h0h1d111x0eU0bx0b0o1d0b0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11x0o0n0cx0c0o0f0c0gx0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l11111100^_)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)
###|
print( (eval ("1\x2f2")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or'({({1})({1}[(0)])}{1}\{1})'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--./
__DATA__=1#//
#.\."12"__*
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#ssseemeePaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjapppp/*/
#define z sizeof'c'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main(   )/*/
#()`#`\'*/{puts(z );}/*'``
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<.>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\
#ss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  =#print(17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#ss*///^_^_Z222999"26
```

[Try them online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zVpLc9tIkj4P/0JfyiDbBEgC4EOSbZGgJVtyr/plrSW7I0zSEggWSVh4NR4SJZmKve7GHuY@lz3O/5jr/or5I71fVoEPvdzdh4lYOggWqrIyszKz8iX/VqQPOwy9y4kXpizlScpGsXvOY4O9umQ7tptsNluFgoCKw1HmuMGEpVPO3CDKUjZ2PZ4UHDtlXRblWAwasCKLuT2SYIVxGDPawvwzj7nMiSI29Oyp4TDPFbBJ6NN6yuMo5ngmLOB8xJKIO@7YdQQdxmcpDxI3DBKDuc4Zu3A9j424hw0r4k4NyFiWrE1JUkZhFBYYPk50h9XlW4kDJuCL4/LIjsVxQxaJsy9OfRHbUQQmC0V2BMZT1@cJc9NywriduCRDbEl4MBKSipbSDZkdrJ@Snbs2s8FvFgvcCY9THM8QeNmUxxwobSI@iW2fqRexm0IEJMhddsjtmB3HnGugAgXwxLEj8HGLJIiFRCGlgxhCUZ1Oef/tmzIUJncYdpQWinHr@N@/L9jMsFjppI2vpSjtwv7Pe@y61KcxuAAyKDWKVVtj1g1LzH6f4ztrDM1JPC8AawFS8ZgZRqkJzHacgr3VSD9vGpG3RpZ17mhizYgk1Ai6YAcB@1AT53KyOObgYiVS@wxH9sJgAmniqHEWkDQCtlWHApwwGCU1xs8hszCQGgovhHyPpy5UlpBC7CHEYzskeXkBhDhxBWB5uTwXdJPQywQcdiYpmR9kgq2E8WDMPrCx7Xq0BeuESnId8yTzUtqTBSPSu@8GfGSwBRtOOCIgPzwHORtIxQTujL920wRTAIYaQnFUWvrnX/82mkyAZ9dxwniUG@sHNgqdzAfDtmDWhiGSuYaB7Qm2AFcj6nI7CJzbnjuyUyIfXOYkBBOC6kWYeSMWgmB84eJiTe1zXMbxmDsplyYeZil4rDHfPpP@wZV2i4P79hCKFQQEbXFsne28hpYcLg1G97N0/Jzp0T4rJ@Yn9eW2@vJJn4M3zdAqJdOctGFtRkVM4a38NcP5sLvSJ1nPsRvSLfKiaQafgZUgieBNYhKmY@M4CTmVFD6vxoZC0MITwdDFFb3g5ZizIe714mDCRqQN0H6d7m2OYaXTBdxtE@OjNQuDdcLI0uSek/DCCxAWvJHjhE0HRNye2CCV5gfalQeSFMXM7aOdBbB0wjbk7Lk@dKEdsgO4mlwZa2cEeKspYYBNam/tUvj2JbA40kWvNMncMZTsw27jS@Zwugy4FVz6OSKSCcNIXNhROGZ1vbm5@TvKT2NzV/9o2vqV@VUd0@HvqHmXjfkF8@xgktkTGHIYYIvtODxK8xuEkyQp7shdNygm9dynG8m0UNq5S1v4ttzbr9Eg7yO1l3tom8wegvIhat3DLWd2PBE3kY3cGPfFu7xLHQDnd4grpwRyi4FT5REWFoEJRsZn3MlSXDcY8sXUdaawXeIukBdWese75DG1Th0uRx8vSRMzje7TZsEwl1PExqModNLofTzw@oSqe2tCKH99Qh4QkfeIoj5c1SLMiluwTAWWZ4cwvqcgEvNfMwgXtudOAgKxg2WIXvNibhKU4dbdxIWEKNiSXR4fvCXf/QuX@QZkJOPOuuMNkX1gex5MaWEhsAJ3piHTA1bOeVAVEfs@gy0ziR0x0NcCvqIZkJZKUhNLC0SfZQ51N/ix7n04QbJcYz1FGdQQb7wE6g4yz8NLFojroHLtGnbh8CQxYNy4gwZlDuBOqXJtfhswncbhBeNzrV1@iNyfVMjrbOjO/h9qxCG@5BOnWlODmPojergH@C9WxD16UMVBgCgD/3slwkFA7i3zM89OZUbghBnkvFQHQoNt1aUGjyGjH5ElsR9dCl5j5FSrXFuk5zPKKvsFJbpMp2HQuu1@lNVKU6Z3H0wf0ciILh8OvMo6KrHhJzc4C4k301@MTupGY/MWCpQH93eO3WQqHrdA77F1f0XsTvzhWDweAAjIFO9YvFjwwyCUxCEhN7DNd@LHgIt9iIPbnuwW@VccOp5w/UXLHLqBOeTjxyDfvHp1IGDGw6H7GBDEQAXQ4vcBsDgbPiQlJDDTe5GO3ZLzcRannj4yU/rl//sfI8j7vjam9mWClPdsOTgJ@AVpRh8/qpx8K72Ix8OK/Jx5KId@B4djU5pre8vBw7i22TsOa0dCEogqCJx6Hi4yRAYHc9@ccRO8bMQXvw8jFTK8HTDl7sD1ddjyllEXCsQrJQGUij2G5U7Ul2ioOoi90B6Zsl5z@UqjUvZ8Zk/C4NJcCylGPPwDrC4CM1sVaOk0SzP5pKrs93TnRvT92hXMIeubu68a@/nPI/BgYusx25XXJoZ30d949pk5pOHJGMOHjyoPE7sTlICL38fAfjmKbIebFwn9PGg2PyGd8lBYH/38/ujwq/YjECLPij35fBDdQeAgqAXp72PCKT3x@DOGJ@zAsT1YX0vaHvVF9DUxuXcE69nDSyrkp3/ehojqpFpleriqVlZtlyh6fJPjPLxJNmbEPidEPcl/L@ogdLg@jtscrQ0ftQk31Fc1USINaUxF4AO@xz63me54dgLTSHPp8nNoQzy@ZqoUIRyymdXoa4Z6h6lFXfpYabPaGblOiOgdCTXTi4eXx4La3exhhYYabuKx2kpvub3ucXtEofbmawYrMop3otOyLH2SWt4gwpwb5w2BZNlzK65WWWD7oiCk8SJZacuqM5mKVgOqwxF85/vAFcmiE8aydpIFuohT//j7KO/ATDhKaN9NkBdNAuoZokCahhcvJd2c@m4U2dTBIRy4rZ5MJ/XXuyy5cFNnKhsvyL/evzl@nlfNef8SL4fkNNe4kOfG0hg82CkXBZ7kZhRyKbic8HLX4lDQW@YH7MIdpVOkaEcuCmFRlS8qRXASExjK85AEX2MHbMTJjYhs@HOGBM4LwzORhBMn//i77BVgEcjANcYL8qJ5tUaRwWobokB3ZLa4QHLF4zAHUUnIsL4MErmE2rmc15gztUUTIzaYvijhiYws41/vHjEdNTy1Xqmib7tjtbT77rsPvfrAumG@iZTCpHxYyE35Vn/WSJQaW4C05xwZ9PpyHcur1TJTSjMlPxa1@URXa2lU0uCYSmOhrkVJ7osOobA7fiFKctF3CehyUesNVUeS4lUTqGWrziqpyEV8FBj6Uco2qT/NIRKMZE@RUccXFMWW0ox9YVOyFd1hjc063qRAPOpo@NYqA1xPus09PsxEqDpvGs2WJY5TOrE6XTGK@SiknlfvU/9iYCYLqfT7s2/rzRnEFsYAf2rSzdn/ee@6ZHTrX74k9iVTlHm5LWoTZVthpevDg8P9o@Pd4/dHEONcywV4mDdzRWPSzhvVsOUsWdzMXH7U0xZ9BdGXps0Cd0luldgOyOrEHVhcZ1BYq00MaY2qalermrbWYt@fwc3BaKnVKVqVhQVnYd6IW2gRl3QqK06UoUs7TJbFIx1hTLfIgyKoOhIRPiFNMFK6wXa9BFY/GkGNw8uUy2JJ1ovLolEpspJtLE9RY0qBYBPrfkMGWr5AVHNO5eaSgBOYk4d6mn1u/vOvf5N9zH6K8X/m4zHG/y3Hn0yS0v3Gl@RxKRoSy4eDQ5bAtciD@/Zs7UyyEoR9BxkKZh8SPBcCIXDJ7Oq8Kzxq7wPkCSVAmGSmZJmCHo8H6jRNo23TJGc8Cb2xIfJ@PoMeYNgGUl3z14zayrhM5tbm1kYDaSXXzxcIRQdkQkmoRKhp20xhhXM3sk6HDut0OkxBoe1xa6stBWmW7E8t5XTJaAmwBem3ewx7sGW1A2vdfJtasqsNjbYyy2LlRpkN2nDJUi@41aoYAESj6SCXhwK3Eeaiohqez1IGa44vF/EIwQD1oE9yEn9cWCDSgUji1pTCPdsFv1gRmaZ7K1Ya62pQfiEwkZduKw@ZDoOF/M8DlhNg/F9y3OvX9ZvBQ43xpe3s3u9/q3e713QWtnMUhFR8vAGvTG2azZbZ2NLW7omSowK3dCu@ACXuAe6Vw93PYZTsvt4/@P7t4dG9/q2ALN8FK7Nyt1Pt60atN1gOyg/Y/DKVPg7PwPFXGpl6ShDu1XpL0813r7U0F1MILGrnFqua7LaunXlBHIabz5QaCqiuKDmFezXXOhuLJHhJdH3n/cMu/B4MJy/6YIv0VzPqsSE4uOBk5wceBPySqbhWvg1rtTOkyrFWW/zZtrZstK@d5N/yGvKuse2Xr70QV6pktkUYas9hV6d91k/7435AxtW@NL8xDbN9rZY869KEP9C6amlqNaqtSrVaCipqKaAb8fQpRa95CRfuxFAMZQYgveRpbbh5XFCrFLRLdkctjaxmRezAKwLDNTbcJKZxXbLnZukp7LuGmZiTG@FqKdEoVakbRmMO/j6HblAya74dXasKU2b09woiX3KrVeLBKJ0QAzdm/6gKznFdjkwRL9u5nzUnflu4o/JtK/3tt2JjizFFnTdbT3Y0hbVM87y/p@60yz173DR@HXx39t13H8tFTWlsKO1go1A0K6dM6T05PDxUm03t6FDtPmPPKrX21vNKDdsatR32F3zYr4Vi9y/QX7e19WQHg9POaaHYGVQ7PaOrD7q9QvG6eDUvFK3O7F2VPr29blV@fsS3ow96s8Mf93eP9mvNjl5s7r2tNY/evyo28LLZXKzQDC23sP5uf3fv7fvjGobfHXzYf3@499ZFEZ@4bnLtzl135@3W2w0znA66VUPXdaM7ABPvZt92b25uqqx6U0nTtGLMCsW97uy9qXeIk2AEEAGu9zXs@FIo9oq9M0hlZta9@nm9cdY4U2cYurP651l9Wp82Ro1GY1bn7@vDWX1YDxsjPDn@1X0M3fp4Vp/Ug3pAQCEGzqzuYDDGc0JLYyD5jH9uvU7Y6@czkPEa4lOvfzrRNrbU59UX@T/riUbJxZeCUK/KVH6OnEFVGv1Zc9xUNERM9YUGU2y0NE1X6xRBN7RPjU5H3drUul11q6lhuaxeq9eNuUaPnlrXBtocoz5NlYvzIl26gG1saogEXPtiWg2zuWHNOqXqTlXfwcfqVjv5z8viSAjYMAsnJ3u7x7snJ1ajaJqFotE3lEZTOTmpEMttykZDjxseXG/rRUHBh8CsIZ@AGG1IkoQj1eKHNs84v8iyC778vEYN9PkzXE8UmRXAjviY0t0rlsDNhOOyU9YbL5XWc@SFrWdKoQhXRL2uDnUFQ2PaLVBHV8Xd0MR2VTstnvbLFfOaKjn1imntuVkpn54WSmWCLBM/eivcCIulUgmWbHSVlvLWKFj0Hx@Ib2JfHKD4Jdxs3ATft4vbUbm1Ue7TQZ5/M5pM3OY37PRL48tWyTTL5eYmY1ZR6q3xTCt2m88M5LTFQT63gblBUfixZgMoKnBCn04@nXxsNpsvXrxQmlu/mebXQgZWl95zzOFYMv8h97kbuz/ZlDYGSxeKwU8ZvPVSbIzk5rlDEtytOSnL9Snxfy8wVyC@hJBpgHrPqYlcllWoHdgbaOxaJMrumKm0igjakAm7LE3SLA5YvV2QQNRUai@HoEJqZhYB0CR5S9W1Gm3mdggZfuFkcwr0WeyoWjT0eKAKLtyB1l7CLDnpYvcaL2v7q1UJPpdsyfM4/kgeW64tX8GeT3W2o@a7tTsAqFEAU@7Xy/kx/8gxkAioSww19qePcWc/4om2OJNgYbWYz69UMS9U0prfLtCxK1G78IPqaNcU59o3/tOnzqeo5w/amm@l9Fut@u154Ux1JUgltXxLb7QjMNtOe9WqO7B87Qc1Esz7Vh3AoE2YE@16qenAytWVaLWrXqDfBIPam15QbQxqWa3y0bqq2Va9NsMXYqt5tV8hvIUo1dS6qgZtu4MvhdxbkoispGq3b03RljPVs6569sCqa20PG6vVNzgM@Ex6XrU60EDcw@L9jW3v6VO76nVnbU/XNYL61Hr5ppdiMKha9L6t2p3Zy6tehv3bKn4tkPE0MI99t3UAfOCvDRlL9a1YlzzOiL0Z2PMtq/LxZeVjxXry5Ko30/1BTYp/u75SPDE/I@bXbUStfFw3LCESUXeryrfu9rdGJWFKDdYHIdeitZ2Sw8pHrESr2zD/Pw)

As usual, I recommend copying the program from the TIO link above (it's in the "Input" box) in order to get it byte-for-byte correct; I've had to replace literal tabs with `␉` and literal ESC characters with `␛` to prevent Stack Exchange deleting them.

Note that there's now a [chat room for discussing answers to this challenge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55553/polyglot-development). Come over if you have questions/suggestions/ideas!

### Rundown

This program prints **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainf***, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .008653 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1018 bytes)

### Verification

Most languages are verified by the TIO link above. For the others:

- I've verified Incident by running it locally on the official interpreter (fixing a number of bugs that had been introduced by token-balancing; specifically, parts of the original Incident program weren't running).
- For Deadfish~, I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the *program to run* interactively. As such, I fed it the polyglot on stdin, but it nonetheless prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, requesting more of the program to be input. I'm assuming that these don't count as part of the program's output, given that they're an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program (and are similar in nature to banners printed by interpreters when they load).
- Reng was tested using [this online interpreter](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP was tested using [this online interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).

### Explanation

#### Deadfish~

This was actually an incredibly easy add.

Deadfish is a fairly infamous language, being almost trivially simple, and has attracted a lot of implementations as a result of being so easy to write, and yet just complex enough to be interesting. The language has a few simple arithmetic operations on an accumulator, and not really anything else. As such, the language's only real use is printing integers other than 256.

Deadfish~ is an advanced version that adds a few extra commands. The ability to halt the program is the most important, meaning that we don't have to ensure that the program as a whole contains exactly one `o`. It also allows us to produce the number 48 in a slightly terser way. (That said, I spaced out a bit while writing this and completely forgot that 49 was a square number, a fact that means that the Deadfish~ code should be substantially golfable. I'm mostly aiming to have something that works, rather than something golfed. Oh well, it means more VIP/20% headroom for the next entry.)

The Deadfish~ code is appended to the end of the INTERCAL; it has to come relatively early, and that's a spot in the program that basically nobody but Cubix is parsing. The code itself is `iisiis{i}ii` ((2²+2)²+10×1+2 = 6²+12 = 48), followed by `oh` to output and exit.

#### Alphuck

Deadfish~ commands are lowercase letters. Alphuck commands are also lowercase letters, so it's not surprising that there was a clash. I had to add a few junk `p` commands to keep Alphuck balanced against the `s` commands in the Deadfish~ code.

#### Incident

Incident was fairly easy to fix when I realised what the problem was; some new tokens had been introduced overlapping two existing Incident tokens, and those were removing parts of the original Incident program. I scattered a few extra `x`s into the code to break up those tokens, restoring the code to how it originally worked.

#### Cubix

The size of the program has changed, and thus so has the size of the cube. I moved Cubix's code to the end of the Deadfish~; it now looks like `@O6O4/` (control flow naturally enters from above, and will hit the `/` and run right-to-left along the Cubix code).

#### Fission

Fission was producing some extraneous output due to the INTERCAL being further left (I'm assuming that there was an unfortunate alignment of two commands that shouldn't have been aligned). I added a useless `x` to the left of the INTERCAL (which can probably be more fruitfully used as part of, say, the Alphuck or Deadfish~) in order to solve that issue.

Comment: Using an abstract language to answer a challenge? AWESOME!

Answer (score 7):

## 55. [Brain-Flak Classic](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brain-Flak/commit/efc8675ce1d4535fd9525821f668589dbea7428d), 1266 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPX (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
'(p(p0 \';case $argv[1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 54;;esac;exit;0';print((eval("2\x2f5")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'\{0}1{0}1{0}1{0}([9]<((((((1)(1)(1))){1}1{1}))0{1}1{1})1>0)5{(<{1}(({1}){1})>0)}{0}({1}(1))'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///^_^_X222999"26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkufGL9QlDdIGQBIbKcqSQdCibblHVeWSxpJd/UxSEggkSVjYCotESabfXGfeHPrelzn2f/R1vqJ/pCYiE1wkUa6qQ783lEkmcomIjD2C/rWCL3IUB9eTIM5JTrOceKl/SVONvLome46ftZstQWC70tgrXD@akHxKiR8lRU7GfkAzwXVy0iVJCUXDAamQlDoe3yaM45TgERJeBMQnbpKQUeBMNZcEPtubxSGu5zRNUgqfGYko9UiWUNcf@y7DQ@gsp1Hmx1GmEd@9IFd@EBCPBnBghdxtADBSZGtTHJUmeLFA4OUm90hdPlUp7Ino4ro0cVJ23Zgk7O6LW1@lTpIAkUKFHAPhuR/SjPi5lBHqZD7yEI5kNPIYp5Ild2PiROu3JJe@Qxygt0gZ7IymOVxPY3DJlKYUQDqIfJI6IZGvUj8HFiAje@SIOik5SSlVAAsIgGaukwAdd1ACshgx5HgRjQmq05H2D99KIDB@QnOSXKikrZN//15wiGaT6pkFb1sULWH/pzfktjrAMVABwECoSSo7CrG/kkwfDCi8Z@ZIn6RzAaAKwJWA6HGS6wDZSXMgbzVSL5taEqyhJZ17klhTIr7LA1mQg4h8bLB7uUWaUqBixVLnAq4cxNEEuAlXTYsIuRGRbQME4MaRlzUIvQSexRGXUHzF@Hsy9UFkGQrEGQF7HBc5zw2AsRNMADSv5OcCbxYHBdsHJ7Mc1Q94AkcR4sGYfCRjxw/wCKwjKE51SrMiyPFMEXko99CPqKeRBRlu7OGmML4EdA4AZRNgM@GapTGiYDOIIWZXxaV//vVv3mQCcHquG6deqawfiRe7RQgEO4xYBxQR1TWOnICRBfsaiJ0fBwSXTuB7To7oo@sSBSOCYb2Ki8AjMSBMr3wwrKlzCcY4HlM3p1zF4yIHGhskdC64f/C53sLFQ2cEgmUIGG52bZXsvQYpuZQrjBoW@XiHqMk@kTL9VH75Qn75ZECBNkVTalVdn1igbVqNTcGT9C3F@dhbyRO158SP0YqCZFqAz4CVKEvAm6TITNeB62ToVHLweQ0yYoxmnggUnZnoFZVSSkZg14uLMR3hOoDnVbTbEsJKpot9d1WMemsaBtoJSpZnD5xEEF8BYkYbOk7Q6QiROxMHUOXlhXr8Qhwjm7l7tYsINB2hjSjZUUc@SAf1AFxNKYy1O8L2VpPvAWhcemtGETrXAMXlLnolSeKPQcgh6G16TVyKxgBWQbmfQyQFU4zMBz2Kx8RQm@32bwg/T/We@kl31Bv9mzLGy98Tc4@M6RUJnGhSOBNQ5DiCI47r0iQvLQhukuVgI/fdIJtUS5@uZVOhuncfN/Ntpbdfw4Heh0uv9NAOqj0wKgRWqwFYOXHSCbNE4vkp2EtwfR87bLi8h1w8xy13CDgXHyFhEZhAyeiMukUO5gaKfDX13SnoLlIXcYPl3vE@ephaxw4uRx0vUSMxZvdZU9D05RSS8SgIFSX6EA54fQTVvTPBhL8@8W3IThZuABwvSQQPtTar6Y4GulcyDaL5MWYS4P4WoZtZ1jK9WPITGPw9BqaU/lKAwECf/UmEW5xoGfbXPKOfRRKECj/zgesYwFHXTw4OMR78THkOA3znsWzdmceQ0cDxMkDjwkIIAnWnMVEjIpU0yCKLp5@BLD1LXTZQ15IIUdGATzLyiy0tAH3medn9gEq6D/cxlFKD9EVx2IAYFmSgQlERBPBQRMzEZKrcgq65NMs0MBjgrYbZCFAn1qkyv7sxn6bxFaFzxZI2ofuDAnldjPzZ/0OJuEgX/4RbrYmBTf0eOTzY@C8WxAN8IIqDCCIX@PQbFmIidJlFWAROzrMMNy6Az0txQLhxbINL8AR49CNkXuRHHwPiGPK0Vf7OUv4ZZqoDQUyu82kcte66NHG10uQp40c9hAinJdebg7m4DoodeOdHFzHSpoeL0Zmhme07IKDkeHhy7GdT9nFn6wOyHq6w01k4GrOPDRsiVMV7Gs8WwjiKOXLgkB85@nv2pYHb3kTBXe94B/0rCjKeUHW3pY/8SB/R8WM73756dcD2jEcj/7FNwAYsqhbfG7alxWgTlyApmj6InuQOn0@KNA9UT8/xm/7vf3jA74fSmDrXGaTRF8vBWUSvUDLq@FHhlEfxgX1sFuTnIoAS6zdguA6mzk6wHGyG9YK8p6DtkORErLICSoMADBlYBg7moTqDJQSFRxffm4EyHt4Nwvx05Icq6PK2ZjABwiMmFpjePQblXibBwWDFkQax4@m8BvTpSqKc93TmTOLoWl8LKVo6@h2kLoI9WRV9@bTIC/6Jld5vyc5P8P0tEyx3Gu3eK3O//HpkPxCx/ZjucrNJwbuobwPnQh/h8GwMw81X5ZdJ/QmUlYvvx7b9fJw4LtWvMvzaqDbvIEULoFg//unD8dE39YcBhNwtDfjnRnAHkQtBLcp/GxLcMmAff0TxmB64TgDa1@K6h70WdY1N/j3GBs7oGpsD0z@uQ4h1Uq8TNV5VQKtWTpI8fsh1Nx/izR52zo2hRqW/FXUgdPghXLfprQ0f1Qk/Vld1VsYVaYyF5Qbf41w6RHUDJwPVyEvu0kuQBvv4lqpihHBRZ1ajbynqPaIWte5j5dLqZOK7MUTvhIkZHwJ4eCyo3c8eVmCwicc@VkfxqdTXN9TxMNR@/abCxm6OVcojKvM7vBEvELAEW9MLLX6MaW58he9HQ/w0vqT8c3MUutlI1e/wNmrAVAKS3AfHWVr1nrWwljVl1ig7bzDnp2WnJVs2MyurVRI5Iau0cbzI2CxezsNFsIcDZbcHAeRD5LOM2Y1TXpTyzgcL1v/4u1e2tiY0z0joZ5AcTiJsxkLlOY2vXnK8JfZekjjYGkMY4LICnlOrr3sku/Jzd8o7WsDnD29Pdsp2RNkYhocjjBxrVPB7w9IYaHByyipnTo0XU649JeLlqcWlQHmLMCJXvpdPIU899iOXsnbHogQHSlLcFuVpjNrXIAfEo@hLWUnwuYAsNojjC1aJICX/@DtvwsAiAAOqYbxAz7qCaxgJyN1knQ@Xp8wLIDc0jcstMjIZTLAAjlyD7lM@rxB36rDuUKoRddEbQTS8P/K6d0zUfSJhTxtbJZY/lqu993/@2DeG9lcS6pBX6VgUML6JT9XnZiY2yGKLNadQRqwvG7C8WpWIWJ2J5bWwf8rahUul4gpHZBwzcS16HSFrvTK9o1es18EaWhF6GOxpQumV5fCoMNC8B2pXZUjIQqiy1OOctLHxT4ElMOLNWoKtdKzb8Uh1Rr6QKeqK6hKzbcATZ0iAraLQXqXB65WH/oaOChavL5tas2Wz61TP7E6XjVLqxdhM7J8OroZ6tuDKYDB7ajRnwLY4he3PdLSc/Z/e3Fa1rvHlS@ZcE1GcSxYr0MQXIqneHh0c7R@f9E4@HAMb50rJwKOyS846vk75CwDocpEtLLPkH/5YwBo2rOGPhxnsKj/KoR2g1jEbWJgzYFgr0DSujbLs1OuKsvbbxf4MfD0oLfaQWQ9YWFAWlx3OhRTBSKe87IZafKmH2bKCxiuM0YoCEASWiCzNyVASBIWukV6QgdZ7HohxdJ1TXjHyonlZOYsVUnW05S0aRBRwb2Y/7HSBlK8gtLvn/HCV7WOQs03N4gHV//nXv/EG8SCH8X@W4zGM/5uPT3Xk0sOOIqdxyRpky8eDI5KBa@EXD53Z2p14OQz6HRWU@CFw8JIxBLdzYlf3XcGR@x@BnyAEYCaqKWomw0fToTzN8@SFrqMznsTBWGPFD52BHECxNcj39V8K7NeDMenb7e0tE3Jrql4uALI20AQzcQ5QUV4QkQiXfmKfj1zS6XSImEEqR@1tizNSrzqnLfF8SWgV9grcb/cJnIEjqxOw1i2PyVWnbip4lNg2kUyJDC1wyVwuYNUyG8AWBaejkh8iuI24ZBU2MugsJ6DN6fUiHkEwgKI4RD6xX20WgFQAxGErovBAd4FeWGHptn8nVmrrYhB/xm0sOX8hblIdAhryPxs0J4Lxf/Fxf2CoX4ebfnFY6k7v4Q8L8v2fBfAuZO84irECewu0ErmpN1u6ua2s2YlYggJq0Sq@AEiwA7Arl/qf4yTrvd4/@P7w6PhBY5ztlO5vk4jU7dQHqtboD5cDaYPOL@uJk/gCKP5Gh1jNcYd/s94r9svT2IhtdnWPXurYsBI0fbEC8UXu3KFY4d3stasvaAD9LWeqpgjIVwhd4UHGt07NoiBYIl0/@fDOC/cH@lMWwKCS@Ksk9hshRvhAyd4PNIroNZHBukIHlNYpoGxIlcbiZ/HG8oeMtZv8W1lP39e5fek2iMGyqrrFopE1B/U6H5BBPhgPItQx61r/Ttd061auBva1Dm5B6crVqW3WW7V6vRrV5GqEhvHsGQaxeRXs7kwTNXEGm9RqoFjg7cFO7WpkVZ2OXPXsZo2dgEeID7dw4Guma7dVZ65Xn4GaN2AmpehNqFzNFMxYDE0z50Df59iPqnojdJJbWSTiDH8PQvRVv15HGrTqGRLwVR8c14FysJpjnYVNq3S3@iS0mFeS7irrr79WzG1CRHnebD3ZUwB4S9drl4M3e5bUd8ZN7Rd3KFUU0dwSrWhLqOi1c3J0cXT0FzCZpnIs9p/I3efkea1hbe/UGnDIbOz9CV7kSJLaLen4VPpFqHT/BGLstraf7MHgvHMuVDrDeqevddVhty9UboXKzVyoCBV71nlfx1f/TbfOX/u9H@Gzow77ydGP@73j/Uazo1aabw4bzeMPryomPLSXT7jUgqf3@703hx9OGk1@5M8HH/c/HL3tvfZ9P8k8L/Pi6bBb11SVqBrpDvtbh9uHe0Jl9rTerdt5npNPZzXQvDfd2Qdd7QD@H4XKe9yvqgNF6w6/CJV@pQ8smzeNwLg0ZuaFefEuPlz9OzyEBX9mfI5TY2pMTc80zZlBPxjXM@PaCOND04NvCn9GCEPfGM@MiREZkWnegfP4v/AwfncYA6gYjuUzI0eoxhi@J4eH7wDYGBB/hj/fMAygz7icAaWByV6nZ4qBiUmnWt@rq3vwsrv1Tvn1suIx5mhfBElO5MQgA8liiXcVW1p9c4hmWjNrCrOwtmFZi@GWZdHMcS0683PLkLjGyTK9dAJZbA5mzXFbVCCSy7sK2IbZUhRVNjCybymnZqcjb7eVblfebiqwLEozMU6lwa0xN9fecn932JHZy1T4P0W5NWHNnCuKsRiZXUNp38odGMsyTuAb5uYIAifhmFSZV9CZRGSrrUCgo8oX3Tb15pY9M7a25Z36bvlnP1F04ezsTe@kd3ZmmxUkTdeFima9F82mKCErLcyw44BqAYST1q4gwqsCm@wRnQAG3J5lFF7hkUMLSq@K4oouX6@hrPv82Ulq4GYsDb1is7m7097ZbTV3Gju7O1ttc7vdbpjNhvl85/mu0TANc8fc3mnvmo2drd3W1tbWLqy2d5/rNaHi0THm/wnJwOHGYymRVPOl2NqBRLn1XBQq4JSxA9rBXnGsTbsC9vmJTBS9pqMdiucVcSDV9FssbcHfKtZcr0niuSgA9E73trLdnuOF5oKH/YmtXbwomLE573RhVJUQnoRzaiveiivVahVM/n1XbImHmmDjf8TBE8ghxiMAVMm@xG3za/S9VXmRSK0taWBXeNEjm8@VSrf5XIOkvzLkk/IWzA0rTOmaJnI22/nOm0z85nfk/Iv5Zbuq65LUbBNibiNLT89Oz/7SBJbu7orN7V91/VvhFlaXIWdMwRsX4aaY00v9dw6m3NEy7sDgXQEhbslhgiwO/BHy@M4cZ/v6FPsPQTAnIF3IPxkHYHBug9UBpMaMb6iQW1Zk@GMi4ypkHyYvdnhZlxdpRAxL4JuwK2kth4AFNYLYuAEnMcTIvm1axO8gMPiGyFRiwNfiRN3GYUAjmVHhDxVruWdJSRdOr9Gydr5e59vnnCx@Hzf0@LX52vIRyAuxR@HK5Wnl3gao72CPNAAHI/zua0ASJS8hNMgfvsa98xCElcWdGAmrxXJ@JYq5UMsboSXgtWuJJfwgu8otJgfW1/DZM/c06YdDSwntHL/r9dCaCxeyz7fUcju0VdNKgFgr79fr/tAOlR/khBEf2gZsBtwIOVNul5KO7FJcmdK46Ufq12jYeNuP6uawUTRqn@ybhmMbjRm8gW2NoPELMG/BSjm3b@qR5XTgjXnKHU4kdlZ3rDtTeORCDuybvjO0DcUK4GC9/hYuA3Rm/aBeHyqAPIDFhwet4Nkzpx50Z1agqgruOm29fNvPYTCs2/j8QnY6s5c3/QLOv5Dh2wY0gQLEw7m7MgB4QJ8FPObiW5HOaZwheTMgL7Tt2qeXtU81@8mTm/5MDYcNzv4XxkrwSPwMiV/XEbn2aV2xGEtYz0IWn/ovnmq1jIgN0D5gciNZO8kprH2ClWRlDfP/Aw)

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .007609 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1336 bytes)

## Rundown

This program prints **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 on my computer.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Brain-Flak Classic does have a TIO but should be verified to run [using this interpreter](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brain-Flak/commit/efc8675ce1d4535fd9525821f668589dbea7428d) as the TIO interpreter post-dates the challenge.

## Explanation

This is my first submission to this challenge, since someone has already done Brain-Flak I have to throw Brain-Flak Classic into the mix.

### Brain-Flak Classic

Brain-Flak classic is the original Version of Brain-Flak.  It has several key differences from regular Brain-Flak.

- `[n]` prints n instead of returning `-n`
- `[]` returns -1 instead of the stack height

Our main competator is thus Brain-Flak itself, due to the increadable overlap.  We then have to exploit one of the
two differences.

We simply cannot abuse `[...]` because as soon as Classic sees `[...]` it will print something and that is a problem.
instead we have to use `[]` to differentiate between the two.  If the stack is empty `[]` will return a truthy value in
Classic (-1) and a falsy value in Brain-Flak (0).  Since standard if syntax works in both languages we can use this to
create an two different numbers in the two languages.  Here is the code I came up with:

```
([]<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68RHWujAQaaIKipWV1bXQsl7TSrNWyqazU0gGwwFygIZANV/f//XzcnOSexuDgzGQA)

This pushes 27 doubles it if it detects Classic and adds one.  It is quite convenient that the language numbers were so
close to a multiple of 2 off.

### Zsh

I began work on this submission while @Chance was working on implementing Zsh.  I hoped that it would not be an issue,
but it immediately was.  See the Zsh Bash polyglot utilizes an if statement that looks like this:

```
if [[ $argv[1] == *"1"* ]];
```

If we look at this the way Brain-Flak sees it:

```
   [[      [ ]          ]]
```

There is no problem, this evaluates as 0 and makes no changes to the stack.  Even if it made anychanges to the stack
those could be wiped with a couple of `{}` and we could be on out way.  However Brain-Flak Classic sees this differently,
Classic sees `print -1 twice` which is *really* bad; no amount of `{}` will ever unprint anything so we need to get rid
of the square braces.

Not knowing Zsh or bash it took me a bit but I was able to replace the `if` statement with a `case` statement that looks
like this

```
case $argv[1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 54;;esac;exit;
```

This is better because it doesn't print anything, but it isn't balanced because of the `)`s so it errors in both the
languages.  This can be remidied by adding `((` earlier on in the program.

Funnily enough implementing this change makes the polyglot *shorter* without breaking anything as far as I could tell.

Now I removed the existing Brain-Flak code (and all those weird symbols inside of it; they can't be that important right?)
and replaced it with the new code.

And what would you know it it worked perfectly, the end.

<sup>except for Alphuck, Japt, Thutu, Incident, and Prelude</sup>

### Alphuck

Alphuck was probably the easiest language to fix.  Since both `case` and `esac` added an `s` two new `p`s had to be added
to the beginning of the line to cancel them out.  That was it.

### Japt

Unlike alphuck, Japt was a real pain.  Japt took the entire mess of parenthesis and brackets that was the new Brain-Flak
code and tried its very hardest to read it as something intelligible.  It failed.

The first thing Japt did not like was `>)`. To Japt the `>` was interpreted as a greater than sign with nothing to operate
on to the right of it.  To fix this I simply had to insert something to the right of it that Japt would interpret as an
object.  This can be solved by just using a one digit number.

The next thing Japt didn't like `{}`.  To Japt this sometimes reads as:

```
(function(){return })
```

It also sometimes reads it as:

```
()
```

Which it also doesn't like

When it reads as which I am not 100% clear on but putting numbers in all of the offending `{}`s fixes the problem.

Next up Japt doesn't know what to do with `()`.  Once again putting numbers in them is the way to go.

Japt was still not very happy with the code complaining about something or other, but it was printing the number so I was
going to spend anymore time fixing what wasn't broken.

### Prelude

All the editing on the line with the Brain-Flak has caused it to become the longest line.  This means I had to move the
prelude code to the end of the current line.  Then Prelude began its complaints about where parentheses were located.
Prelude does not allow Parentheses on different lines to be in the same column.  This gets to be a problem when the code
you are editting around is made almost entirely of parentheses.  In fact every edit from now on is pretty much followed with
and then I had to go realign all the parentheses because Prelude is complaining.

### Thutu

Thutu had two main problems.

- Nested quatifiers `{1}{1}`
- `[]`

Nested quantifiers arises because Thutu is interpreting Brain-Flak as regex and doesn't know what to do when `{...}` is
followed by `{...}`.  It is fixed by putting things in between the two.  It also doesn't like `[]` because regex.  This
is fixed with my favorite stategy of slapping a number inside of the braces.

### Modular SNUSP

Since I was working while @Chance was the Zsh changes that broke SNUSP for him also broke it for me.  I implemented a
nearly identical fix for it so you can read #54 for the details.

### Incident

All that was left broken was Cubix and Incident.  I probably should have chosen to fix cubix first, but I didn't, I decided
to go with Incident.

Incident is one of my favorite languages to fix.  It requires a massive balancing act across pretty much the entire
program.  I'm still not clear on how Incident works.  The thing I was told is that I want `0mo` to be the middle token
in the list of tokens.

Amazingly I seemed to in my destructive romp all over the 17th line of the program caused minimal damage to the program.
The `((` I added to the begining of the line caused `(p` to become a token.  In order to fix this I changed `((pp` to
`(p(p`.  This caused the parser to see `(p` 4 times instead of 3 and ignore it as a token.  This would not be the end
of Incident

### Cubix

Asside from some [font confusion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36983074#36983074) Cubix was pretty easy
to fix.  Since the board had resized I just had to move the "capsule" that had conveniently been made for me by my
predecessors to the right place.  Because Cubix quickly became stuck in an infinite loop this was a tad tricky but I ended
up being able to manage.

### Prelude *(again)*

With the Cubix fix Prelude was back, with a vengence.  Prelude had as I mentioned popped up a couple of times before but
ultimately been easy to squash.  This time I had to make nearly two dozen separate adjustments before Prelude would run.

### Incident *(again)*

Of course fixing Prelude broke Incident.  It created 9 new tokens that had to be removed in order to get the code to run.
And of course removing the tokens once again broke Prelude.  At this point It was starting to feel like Whack-a-mole,
every fix I would make would break either Incident or Prelude, which of course would both break each other.  After a couple
rounds of back and forth I was able to get them to cooperate.  The result is a delicate balance that will surely wreak
havoc on the next competator.

## Going forward

Dealing with Brain-Flak Classic in the future should be only slightly worse than dealing with Brain-Flak itself.  The one
thing it *really* doesn't like is `[...]`.  These can be commented out for the most part.

I just dug up an old Brain-Flueue interpreter that predates this challenge so I think for my next attempt I will try to
implement that one.

Answer (score 7):

## 66. [Surface](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page), 1650 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>.+?+++++::@
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVE4O6O@UPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[' ];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.

#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f2")and 9or 13)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWW li ha '#}#( prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("'3)3)3)"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi ax fwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm 
# sss8␛dggi2␛`|$// ''25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_2229996#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrLcttIkufGL/SlDLINgCRepCRLAkmJtqVZd9strSU/wiQtl8AiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzE/0ptZBb5ESu6O2I1YSAIKqKzMrHxVZZZ@L@BFTiP/ZuBHGclYmpFe4l2zxCBPb8gh9dLtak2SOFQS9UauFw5INmTEC@NRRvqez1LJpRlpkjjHYmCDFEjCaE@ASf0oITiEBFc@8Ygbx@TSp0PDJb7HYdMowP6MJXHC4J6SkLEeSWPmen3P5XQIm2QsTL0oTA3iuVdk7Pk@6TEfBiyIuxVARkbp0idBypB6kUTgcuM7rM7figxgQjabLotpwqcbkZjPfTbrcULjGJiUCuQMGM@8gKXEy5SUMJp6KEMYkrKwxyUVz6UbERouz5Jce5RQ4HeUcNwpSzKYnsHxkiFLGKCkSHyQ0ICo48TLQAQoyBY5ZTQh5wljGlABBbDUpTHwsUISiEVIIcOJGFxR9bpydHKsgMLECIPGmVRIauf/@rNEidEgxQsH/hqy7EhHvz4nt8UOtoELQAZKjROVaqTxjaRmp8Pgb2JfmoNkKgFWCaTiEzOKMxMw0yQD9hYt/bpqxP4SWVK/o4klIxJQPdAFeRGStxU@L3eUJAy4WIiUXsGU/SgcgDRhqskoRGmEZMcCBbhR2EsrhF2DzKJQaCgac/meDz1QWYoKoZcgHuqi5IUDcHGCC4Dl5fKc0U0jf8ThYGSaofmBTGAoYnzRJ29Jn3o@DoF@RCW4Tlg68jMcMwp7qPfAC1nPIDM23KiHQEF0DeQoIOUfwGeCJU/jTAEwqCHiU8Wuf/71b73BAPC0XDdKermxviW9yB0FwDDlzFIwRDTXKKQ@ZwvgKkhdDAcC19T3ejRD8uFNToIzwamOo5HfIxEQTMYeONaQXoMz9vvMzZgw8WiUAY8VEtArER88Ybcw8YBegmI5AU6bT1snh89ASy4TBqMHo6y/S/T4iCip@VE92FcPHnUY8KYZWqlomgMHrM0o8U/wpjxkOG9bC32i9Zx7EXqRHw9HEDOgJ0xjiCYJCtOlMJ0Ug0oGMa9CLrmgeSQCQ@cuOmZKwsgl@PVsYtxGhA3geB39Nsew0OkMbtXEWG/JwsA6wciydC1I@NEYCHPeMHCCTYdInA4okMryCbXEhARF/mV1alchWDpiu2RkV7/0QDtoBxBqcmUszRHAa1UBA9iE9pacIqA3gMUVIXqhSeL1QckB2G1yQ1yGzgBewUScQyIjbhipB3YU9YmlV7e3v6P8LDFb@geT6l/MB3WMk7@j5hbpszHxaTgY0QEYchTCEOq6LM5yD4KZpBn4yN0wyD/qeUw30qFUPLxLm8e2PNov0cDoI7SXR2iKZg@CCkDUug9eTmgy4J5Iel4C/uLf3KUOANd3iMufEGSFgU/yPSzMFiYwMjZh7igDdwNDHg89dwi2i9yFwmFFdLxLHj4tU4eQo/fnpJEZu/m4Khnm/BOycS8KHTW6jgeiPqJqrnzgyl/@8DBmmgYbEEdzFiFCLX01TGqA7eVCg9X8DHcSEP5mSzf3rPn2Yi5PEPDPuDAl7LcRKAzs2RuECELD@bK/FBm9NFRgqfBSD6SOCzja@vmLE1wP3jGxhwG5i7VsOZhHsKOB4fkCjR0zJUjMHUZED4mS86DKfD39DGyZaeLyhr60iZA1A@Skorx41wzRZ7Evu7ugkuY6HCepVEhblrsVWMP8FEwoHPk@vIxC7mIq027B1lyWpgY4DMjWwN0IcCeXmTZdBcyGSTQmbKo5yiZyf1Ihz0aX3uT/oUZc5EvcYVZLauCf/oge1gBnipDlXHRrEEJ458DeS9j0kJcerkV92CItts58tz3BTWJHkuObbBiFtdVoIi96qmK39tYMYHEx4pvN66i8jIoPeOWFVxFqyQxmrQvLsLdXUMBuf31k30uH/LYCusbWeg8fnQaXfX7bABCiFdwxNt4RRGEkiIOEvJCar/nDgIi5iYPVwLRC/ikDOx8wfa9mXnqhecn690EeP336gsP0Ly@9@4BADJjPzJ4bwJLR5SYpwX5kuLZwkRU5n4@SzNd7ZoZP9t//1gN5r2tjSG9S2MFezRsXIRujZvT@vcrJh@ILv21W5OeRD9nNd3C4FHet1J83NuPaJ68ZWDvsL0Ke1ACnvg8@BCID3143Z/AEf9Rjs@dmpFyGq@ufGB16gQ62vGNYXIHwims67qzuw3JnERdocLOf@BHtmSL98thCo0L2bEIHUXhjLkVzI7n8A6zO1lmyyLey4SgbiTsmWd/TnRfj30MumENa262n9lH@uAcemNi5z3aF2yQQXfRjn16Zl9i86ENz81TFZBJvABnd7Hkf2LuzmLrMHKf42Gg2r2B35EOefPbrm7PTB@2HI4RtU@KL@0Z0L0IX1pMw@z4mmKXPb3/G8LgduNQH66sJ28Myh74kJu@OYH16eYN5@fDP2xBSHZTLRI8WyceiihLH9w9y3c2DRJ2Fj3MjSA/Z91YdWDq8AKZb7S0177UJL9IXKU4qDKmPOd2G2EOvKdFdn6ZgGlkuXXYN2uC3h0wVVwgXbWbReshQ7zA1SzPvy1QWI2PPjWD1jrma8cWHl/sWtbvbgAUarJ/x22IovuX2@pzRHi613x402MjNMEG4x2T@QDQSe3PMfpbswojuE5objfHv3iV@GF0zcd@8Cn3ZyNUfiDa6z00C9pfrw3vu96z1nZdCrIHb5ih4tZGrzPU3fsfQFCWQnKWkalgPqmejMZ8ZL4yXxolxRs48P0oflAekpmkq7ptNeQF6mXg01F204eX25mEbGeMrGmnx@z0Kpv4g8nd2ByaF20bZnI2SPob0B8QiNsKveb1vnoCnlbxMCd@8JC9LpfPKbwHid8J4Oj5LMEgBiwSjAPw8ixKDcDhVpeWypkliEFrMIASwGRSvvmEBRBT2UgKum3FYr0/abVK8nexb@/aUNIi8L5NuV2DlqfjRJOZls9diaLtIu42i8v69UlQ64T6xFA7KIAPbDEpX4Poefwg@F1MnIQ14zQXbs5k6orADfoXVvCENe7CfeRN6PHdyo0SUJ0QNjO8d//H3Xl7kHDCYZOCl1AdBYFk@CtgwGh8Iujn1VhxTLJIiDlhBfZFd6c9aJB17mTsUtU1w@zfH57t5YSo/IoCXU9zILHEhlApdfeCBZkJpgptexIRZ5ITno2aTglg6CkIy9nrZMDXAQUKX8cLXrBgDnCQIFmZJhGZVIS9Ij@HSzpPDzyPQrR9FVzwnRU7@8XdRjoNOD00I2zPyvD68RJGAL9m8Bua60Qi4niH5wpIoB1FRyLAijEAiN2DUTHzXiDukvE4IlqjPqmRIRlTKnrXOiH5EFDzdwKKZ4/XVYuv1X962rW7jGwlM2OabmKdzuck/6U/sVK6QGYgzRbta7rage9GrELk4kfNpYSWdF47nRiW8iajY5uqaVb0CXoTndsfGvOrFS5shLnhY3YYkPM3gVeOohdM0iirkBwHk2/pZRrbxCIiBSKAlyvYED1WwgoNDihPylQzRVnSX2NsWvAmB@Fg0DBqLrGw5ETafs8sR3z5eV41qrcGnU7xo1Ju8lbBehGXl9sfOuGumM6l0OpOfrOoExBYlAP7YRM85@vX5bdFoWl@/pvQGsvOp4vBUHd27eHv64vTo7Lx1/uYMxDgVsywcR0lAFyECjSD2IaYNI5/X6UEeicfS74eNeejIBSe/fy8XRTuPASQPVOSU6ypXi5IuB6nKTH04dfCoEUTFGWlQ@@2GYMOZkUkD2HkP7KwyM3/LkagqKVJSJ7ZFNG21l8MLcR3ARUBkS@zPLh7yFlCbgXCuAjjnW8AIJjdOYvq/xPlp6@zs@5wj1Pc4B2Dpe9SXCB@3XrxcJ7xEEwHW@vOFAR6LA82jCexCIX71uWVi2XxmMVF@7DFzaIjXQ1GLo/4iJKXzshraUB8Dqg8@icbME7AUnZKg/xuk5acQAHs98OjLmwwDAkRCUUmbl9PkAkzdmK9PFSJLCJs21svf4PBjSDrcT2JwkcNxzOmmE6QOM//517@JU6NOBu1/z9t9aP@naH80UUDrxwyCx7loUCxvX5ySFFYZMfGATpbmhIEeFxIvHMF2JQAJXnOBILhgdjHfBR61/RbkCUoAYWLEwiDF6bGkqw6zLN43TVyXYZ/UN3hZhk1ADxDjDDcKzN9GeIgHcdXc2d7ZsiHrZ/r1DCGvDQ@wRiAQato@2I907cWNT5cuqdfrRE4hyWSNHUcI0izSjzX505zRIsBKYglvExgDQxYjoK@ZD1OLtGxrOBT9T7EV0nVgdRZ6gQCv8gaAaPg5zOUhwwoS5aLCMjObZDwY3sy2JrAvCCMSoJz4Ue4MkQ6IBG5NltZsF/iFHl4I8Fb2hMayGuR3CMbLBvvyJtMhYCH/tcFyQmj/h2i3O5b@rbvpGHJuO63100b17lkhzoUcnoUR1oaOgVeiVs1qzbR3tCU/kXNUwC16xVdACX4AfuUy73MUp61nRy9@Pjk9Wzst45DKXTCFKM16uaMblXZ33lDu2PxMpE@PzbNXT49nglzmKu@6y9Um5HcZu4fYO1F0WSfFO9YI2dYfRbzIBjdOZJErLgE@E2niGlVVu522u/VmJyyskf@66Si7YJTw9BpanZQfZCtkQ4CZl5XOoyswjwfO6PQMIbwvy6d1Xj4aj8KqTbPHrk08u5EMc9YDa6NaX@FWE@eJQgYz8hAn8i9FWwa6C1qutJbzLzMyKwnN6S2PXJ/ubJkBP81LoOD6@C8heNgD2zIPODn8hYUhuyEqRLGAQnCgI0jFE60y@5@kyvwUeUmb/5JXVO/69pFy60cQwYqmwzeAzhTc@FOHdLJOvxOiLzs35o@mYTq3atFv3JgQfrWmWhw27HKtVC4Xw5JaDDEAPX6M@8ZpEeLbhSEb8gSA9KKvObCqQjxsFEOnSOtqsdeolvgIeIVc8hYGfEtN47ZIp2bxMYSTCnxJGEZtphZTDfeHlmHYU@Dvc@SFRbMS0PhWlYk8wcN4JF/0ymXkwSheIAPfzM5ZmRtX58zkO1UnX9bMQeDw6K@s2ujvvxfsHUJkdRqVD6q1R4earsqmWeo8v3aUNu1Xjd@6p1enp@@VwrMTTba3ZCfckgpmyfr6xDQ/ffoEkZ6Qtq5cd9uP1OaTJ6WKs7Nbqhw6il05tK0ffrBtTa1WtbMfflBtcqoo2zXl7KPym1Ro/gDKre08Ovzhk1SQChfNMlxG0ygfYKO8v38oFT7Voa/enU5Jud6uG82m3m22pcKtVPgyxUGNSf01h24/58Ph2t6bvIRHXe@249OXR62zo0q1rheqz08q1bM3Tws2vGzP37CrBm@vj1rPT96cV6piyF9evD3aOtk5OXxzetx65nlenPZ6aS8adpuHh2VD1/VDo9kFTiY/lZvlRpZl5MNFCaz1eXPyxtTrwMBLqfCaQ@odDWC/SoV2oa0eVA@qlm9dWxP7yr56FZ0sfk9OoMObWJ@jxBpaQ7tn2/bEYm@sm4l1YwXRid2DJ4MfK4CmZ/Un1sAKrdC2V/Dc/xucRK9OIkAVwbBsYmWI1erDc3By8gqQ9YHwZ/jxLMsC/ibWNfxavs2vjxeWpUmwxe5u78TVnd/aWEgh23vdNpt4WVcmFaXTxgW/YKadjinMTa6CxWD/dHpx8bx13rq4MFFxhcKkXiwflvVDuBrNcj1/HBR6TZSaAfFBUlTYC8cdxaEN6vBsu4jHKm27Wy7e0v3RFONFyS5p3NW3LccptUj@sgUveXPXcVhKXc6Gowi@VJVdU1@V7c6k2q/KGm7j9sDh7Bo4gIVvW9pHu15Xd7a1ZnOnqkWJrEzkKFHI7VT8qLfTusovDX80DT/m96Z2q9YBBGA0/irgAWr87t07/Hs3vh6LFm@Ib@/mncsveMEmmgwpUQrTgsoTcLK1rcEmiGlbO@pueS//aTzSgB9ZqWn4IyvSTOgNu4D8SwXDeS3bVegBFTiYiEc@M3zYatT2JBkuqXHJBl4o1Zu3YU8qpCmDKzilbMTYeDQas/n1zEv36efPNIb1zHQMDOXV6t7u9u5erbpb2d3b3dq2d7a3K3a1Yj/ZfbJnVWzL3rV3drf37Mru1l5ta2trD3q3956YJanQY32sE8QkhVUi6iuxotsHcm0XEt/aE2AcVhI8uKvjEWdkDJsSHk8TlWi3aIcgFM2ZAh5RnNixpcJU6mH9fGvPwYAxrTelooJjlJpU0GvRVlQoFosQXc6bck0@MVKpwWDGIIKCjIML6eRrtG1/C392CvuxUttSap1GQRiP/UQrNKtPDEj9C13xjahb8LFb4CZXtQtk4v1f/UK20R8vWc2qJW1oLK65Sa0Z2FJrw/v4OsD/00rTdPfH3mDgVX/89BX2LkRRqtuE2DtoAt/0uvitw@39sxMhKnlnW9YK6ceLjxdVMI@9vZ3C7zDwgZ0O9M6X/D6D1XAUbFrzW4n3imJqGc7XfWi8GsEWY24sBK3F9y7RXFa@CQta/sT/Gxa@ScgXmomKDQg3boXnu6TEQ09XI7ezKomKvZioa/O8PmHZKAmJ5Yj6C6LwnHkTqKBxkwYC8GQcIo7qNWyHeHVEBk/YGeQU8JqNKDew6bNQ5Vx4Xc2RlgsWnJMmjF7iZWl8uSzAp4ItMR836Ilpi775K7AXYFnWVfPR2h2AttUFGKVjKfk0/8g0YP@qzjFUyJ@exp3xsAnSZnPiLCw68@8LVUylUlYJHAmnXYod6RfV1W5xc@Z8Cx4/dj/G7aDraEEjw2e5HDhT6Ur1BEgpawQN3XZiYNbJ2uWy120E2i9qzJkPGhYAA23EnGq3c02HjVxdqVb50g71b2G3ctwOy3a3MqqUPjS@VGjDqkzgD8RW8Su/gfBmolSzxpdy6NA6/OE@cUUScSMtU2e1jgRDrlS/8aVNuw1Lc3wYWC4fw2SAz7Ttl8tdDYj70Lk@0PEfP6ZlvzlxfF3XEOpj7eC4nUGjW27g@75K65ODL@0RjN9X4dkAMr4GzMO4VR0APuDPARkL9S1YFzxOkL0JsBc0GqUPB6UPpcajR1/aEz3oVoT4962F4pH5CTK/bCNq6cOyYXGR8DKtKv/k7f9klFIiV8D6QMiVeGmk4LD0AXrihTdM/wc)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005739 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1726 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 7 languages have to be tested locally (I'll try to get a TIO for surface).

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 using [this interpreter](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip) run using Wine (It probably works on Windows but Windows is not a free software, so it would be forbidden for this challenge (I also don't have it so I can't test it anyway))

### Explanation

Surface is an interesting language I discovered when I was writing the esolangs page for my new language [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein).  Surface is a 2D language embedded on a Klein Bottle (most 2D languages are embedded on tori).  I thought it was an interesting language and It would make a good addition.

---

#### Adding Surface

The first thing I did was to run the existing program in Surface (worth a shot right?).  Unsurprisingly it did not print 66, but rather got stuck in an infinite loop.  This is because the `(...)` in the first line functions as a loop with no exit condition.  In order to fix this we need an escape.  I tried a few things but the simplest seemed to be to add an `o` inside the loop.  This `o` would send the ip downwards where it could be caught by a later part of the program.  Luckily (by design) there is a `>` only 5 lines down.  This redirects our ip to the right it passes over 6 `+`s bringing the total up to 6 two `:`s which output the 6 twice and finally we terminate with a `@`.

#### All of the other 2D languages

Adding a `o` to the first line screwed with pretty much every single other 2D language.  We first had to add a `v` to the second line to realign the Befunge, I had to add an `x` to the 3rd to last line to realign Reng, Reticular and Haystack.  Minimal 2D needed an `x` on the 12th line.

#### The Usual Suspects

Of course Prelude, Cubix and Incident all broke.  I had a particular amount of trouble with fixing Cubix, but after some refactors it boiled down to just moving the capsule.  Prelude was simple to fix.  Incident had some weirdness but ended up working itself out.

Answer (score 7):

## 70. [Commercial](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Commercial), 1804 bytes

````
#16  "(}o+?23!@)-("//*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX'#CO)"14";n4
#/*0|7//```"`   [-'v][!(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@10␉␉11)(22)S␉␉(1 P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@-----x-.+?
#`<`
#<]}} +<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#x}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++59xL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_00)
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
#
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
#
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in *1*)echo 50;;*A )echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{}) ){}{})>){(<{}(({}){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{nd
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai are at are "6"
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( ){puts( p);}/*
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.s
=end
"""#"
#}
#sx|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21# xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
#s a8␛dggi2␛`|$// '' 25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-XCOprint("65")#s^_^_222999 rk:start | print: "69" & s rk:end |6#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005259 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1882 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTrLcttIkufGL/SlDLINQCRepEhLAklJtqVZd9strSU/wiQtF8EiCQuvBkCRskzHXndjD3Ofyx7nP@a6XzE/0ptZBT4kUnJ3xG7EQhJQQGVlZuWrsrLUo@no998LeJHTyL8e@lFGMpZmpJ94VywxyNNrckC9tFapShKHSqL@2PXCIclGjHhhPM7IwPNZKrk0Iy0S51gMbJACSRjtCzBpECUEh5Dg0iceceOY9Hw6Mlziexw2jQLsz1gSJwzuKQkZ65M0Zq438FxOh7BpxsLUi8LUIJ57SSae75M@82HAkrhbBmRknK58EqQMqR9JBC43vsPq4q3IACZk8@mymCZ8uhGJ@dzns54kNI6BSalAzoDxzAtYSrxMSQmjqYcyhCEpC/tcUvFCuhGh4eosyZVHCQV@xwnHnbIkg@kZHC8ZsYQBSorEhwkNiDpJvAxEgII8JKeMJuQ8YUwDKqAAlro0Bj5ukQRiEVLIcCIGV1SjoRydHCugMDHCoHEmFZLq@b/@LFFiNEnxwoG/piw70tGvz8lNsYNt4AKQgVLjRKUaaX4jqdnpMPib2j1zmMwkwCqBVHxiRnFmAmaaZMDesqVfVYzYXyFLGnc0sWJEAqoPuiAvQvK2zOfljpOEARdLkdJLmLIfhUOQJkw1GYcojZDULVCAG4X9tEzYFcgsCoWGogmX7/nIA5WlqBDaA/FQFyUvHICLE1wALC@X55xuGvljDgcj0wzND2QCQxHjiwF5SwbU83EI9CMqwXXC0rGf4Zhx2Ee9B17I@gaZs@FGfQQKoisgRwEp/wA@E6x4GmcKgEENEZ8qdv3zr3/rD4eA59B1o6SfG@tb0o/ccQAMU84sBUNEc41C6nO2AK6M1MVwIHBFfa9PMyQfXuckOBOc6iQa@30SAcFk4oFjjegVOONgwNyMCROPxhnwWCYBvRTxwRN2CxMPaA8Uywlw2nzaOjl4BlpymTAYPRhngx2ix0dESc2P6v6euv@ow4A3zdC2iqY5dMDajC3@Cd6Uhwzn7eFSn2g9516EXuTHozHEDOgJ0xiiSYLCdClMJ8WgkkHMK5MeFzSPRGDo3EUnTEkY6YFfzyfGbUTYAI7X0W9zDEudzuFumxjrr1gYWCcYWZauBQk/mgBhzhsGTrDpEInTIQVSWT6hQzEhQZF/uT21yxAsHbH1GNnRex5oB@0AQk2ujJU5Ani1ImAAm9DeilME9BqwuCJELzVJvAEoOQC7Ta6Jy9AZwCuYiHNIZMwNI/XAjqIBsfRKrfYd5WeJeah/MKn@xXxQxzj5O2o@JAM2IT4Nh2M6BEOOQhhCXZfFWe5BMJM0Ax@5Gwb5Rz2P6UY6kooHd2nz2JZH@xUaGH2E9vIITdHsQVABiFr3wcsJTYbcE0nfS8Bf/Ou71AHg6g5x@ROC3GLgk3wPC/OFCYyMTZk7zsDdwJAnI88dge0id6FwWBEd75KHT6vUIeTogwVpZMZuPa5Ihrn4hGzci0JHja7jgaiPqFq3PnDlr354GDNNgw2IowWLEKFWvhomNcD2cqHBan6GmQSEv/nSzT1rkV4s5AkC/hkXpoT9NgaFgT17wxBBaLhY9lcio5eGCiwVXuqB1HEBR1s/f3GC68E7JnIYkLtYy1aDeQQZDQzPF2jsmCtBYu4oInpIlJwHVebr6Wdgy0wTlzf0lSRC1gyQk4ry4l1zRJ9FXnZ3QSWtdThOUimTtix3y7CG@SmYUDj2fXgZh9zFVKbdgK25LE0NcBiQrYHZCHAnl5g2uw2YjZJoQthMc5RN5P6kQp6Ne970/6FGXORL3GFWK2rgn/6IHtYA54qQ5Vx0axBCeOfA3ktIeshLD9eiAaRIy9SZZ9tTTBI7khxfZ6MorN6OJvKypyKytbdmAIuLEV9vXkflVVR8wCsvvIxQS2Ywb11Yhl27hQKy/fWRAy8d8dst0DW21nv46DToDfhtA0CIVnDH2HhHEIWRIA4S8kJqvuYPAyLmJg5uB6Zb5J8ysPMh03erZs8LzR4b3Ad5/PTpCw4z6PW8@4BADLifmT83gCXj3iYpQT4yWlu4yC05n4@TzNf7ZoZP9t//1gd5r2tjRK9TyGAvF42LkE1QM/rgXuXkQ/GF3zYr8vPYh93Nd3C4FLNW6i8am3HtkdcMrB3yi5BvaoBT3wcfApGBb6@bM3iCP@6z@XMzUi7D2@ufGB16gQ62XDcsrkB4xTUdM6v7sNxZxAUaTPYTP6J9U2y/PLbUqJA9m9JhFF6bK9HcSHp/gNX5OkuW@61sNM7G4o6brO/pzovx7yEXzCGt2uFT@yh/3AMPTNTvs13hNglEF/3Yp5dmD5sXA2hunqqYTOINYUc3f94H9u4spi4zJyk@NprNK8iOfNgnn/365uz0QfvhCCFtSnxx34juRejCehJm38cEs/T57c8YHrcDl/pgfVVhe1jm0FfE5N0RrE9717gvH/15G0Kqw1KJ6NFy87GsosTx/YNcl@gQe5ru7u7m0aLgwhG4EewT2feWH1hDvADmXemvNO81Di/Sl3udVFjUADd3G4IQvaJEd32ago1kuZjZFaiF3x6yWVwqXDSeZeshi73D1Hy/ed@WZTky9twIlvGY6xtffHi5b3W7mw8s0WAhjd@WQ/EtN9znjPZxzf32oOVGboY7hXts5w@EJZGk4zZoxS6M6D6hudEE/@5d60fRFRP3zcvRl41c/YGwo/vcJCDRXB/ed79nre@8FIIO3DaHw8uNXGWuv/E7xqgogV1aSiqG9aB6NhrzmfHCeGmcGGfkzPOj9EF5wB41TcV9sykvQXuJR0PdRRtebW8etpExvrSRQ36/R8HUH0Z@fWdoUrhtlM3ZOBlgbH9ILA/HKNv@boxaZDNRaOfP@zhOLuF3I6fPYNcPwRu3NA8wy7P317xIuagapOW8tgrfvCSvpaWLcnUBFp2E8RrCfFdECljZGAcQk7IoMQiHU1VaKmmaJAahdQ9DAJtD8ZIhVm1ENTIlEGYyDusNSLtNijfTPWvPnpEmkfdk0u0KrLx@cDSNea3vtRjaLtJus6i8f68UlU64RyyFgzLYNm4GpbfgBh5/CD6XUychDXihCNvzmTqiGgUxAEuQIxr2IQl7E3p8w@dGiaipiMIdT3j/8fd@XpkdMphk4KXUB0HgWUIUsFE02Rd0c@qHcUyxsos4YNn3xZZQf3ZI0omXuSNRkIUQ9eb4fCevpuXnGvByitnXChdCqdA1AB5oJpQmuOlHTFhFTngxaj4piPvjICQTr5@NUgOcOXQZr9bNK0jASYJgYZZEaFVl8oL0GeYjfEf7eQy69aPokm@kkZN//F3UEKHTQxPC9pw8L2qvUCTg9zYv3LluNAau50i@sCTKQVQUMqxeY5DINdg0E9814o4oL26CJerz0h6SEeW9Z4dnRD8iCh7JYKXP8QZq8fD1X962rW7zGwlM2JuYWFzgcpN/0p/YqVwmcxBnhna12m1B97JXIXJxKufTwvI/r3YvjEp4E1GxzdU1L9UF/OSA2x2b8FIdr8eGuDhjST5MwT/gVeOohdM0iypsagIvI/pZRmp4bsVAJNASZw0ET4Kw7IRDilPylYzQVnSX2DUL3oRAfKx0Bs3lVnJ1924@Z70xz3mvKkal2uTTKV40Gy3eSlg/wlp4@2Nn0jXTuVQ6nelPVmUKYosSAH9soucc/fr8pmi0rK9fU3pNZHmmOLy@gO5dvDl9cXp0dn54/uYMxDgTsywcR0lAlyECjSD2If6OIp8fLoA8Eo@l3w8bi9CRC05@/14uinYeA0geqMgp11WuFiVdDVLlufpw6uBRY4iKc9Kg9psNwYYzI5MmsPMe2LnNzOItR6KqpEhJg9gW0bTbvRxeiGsfLgIiW2F/fvGQt4TaDIRzFcA53wJGMLlxErP/Jc5PD8/Ovs85Qn2PcwCWvkd9hfDx4YuX64RXaCLAWn@@MMBjeQp7NIWMGeLXgFsm1vrnFhPlZzVzh4Z4PRIFRFiCFyEpXdQC0YYGGFB98Ek0Zr5rTNEpCfq/QQ79FAJgvw8e3bvOMCBAJBTlv0UNUC7A1I3F@lQmsoSwaXO9Zg8OP4EsxP0kBhc5HMecbjr26jDzn3/9mzjq6mTQ/ve8PYD2f4r2RxMFtH42InhciAbF8vbFKUlhlRETD@h0ZU4Y6HEh8cIxpFYBSPCKCwTBBbPL@S7xqO23IE9QAggTIxYGKU6PJV11lGXxnmniugw53cDgtSQ2BT1AjDPcKDB/G@PJI8RVs16rb9smMKlfzRHygvYQCxsCoabtgf1IV17c/NRzSaPRIHIKO2PWrDtCkGaRfqzKnxaMFgFWEkt4m8AYGLIcAX2tfJhapCVbw6Hof4qtkK4Dq7PQCwR4lTcARMPPYS4PGVaQKBcV1sbZNOPB8HqemkBeEEYkQDnx8@c5Ih0QCdyaLK3ZLvALPbx64d3KCY1VNcjvEIzXOvbkTaZDwEL@a4PlhND@D9Fudyz9W3fT2enCdg7Xj0jVuwecOBdycBZGWNA6Bl6JWjErVdOuayt@IueogFv0iq@AEvwA/Mpl3ucoTg@fHb34@eT0bO2Ij0Mqd8EUorQapY5ulNvdRUO5Y/NzkT49Ns9ePT2eC3KVq7zrLlebkN9l7B5i70SlaJ0U71gjZFt/FPFy57pxIst97QrgM7GlXaOqajezdrfR6oSFNfJfN52/F4wtPHKHViflp@8K2RBgFrWw8@gSzOOBg0U9Qwjvy@oRo5ePxvO7SsvssysTD5wkw5z3wNqoNm5xq4lDUCGDOXmIE/mXoi0D3SUtV1qrT6wyIvaI0YKTWyPXpztfZsBP87otuD7@HwueUEFa5gEnB7@wMGTXRIUoFlAIDnQMm8lEK8//kaq8OPpe0ea/5GXgu759pNz4EUSwounwBNCZgRt/6pBO1hl0QvRl59r80TRM50Yt@s1rE8Kv1lKLo6Zdqm6VSsVwSy2GGIAeP8a8cVaE@HZhyIY8BSC96GsOrKoQD5vF0CnShlrsNytbfAS8wl7yBgZ8S03jpkhnZvExhJMyfEkYRm2mFlMN80PLMOwZ8Pc58sKiWQ5ofKPKRJ7ifxAg@aJXKiEPRvECGfhmds5K3Lg6ZybPVJ18WTOHgcOjv3LbRn//vWDXCZHVWVTar1QfHWi6KpvmVuf5laO06aBi/NY9vTw9fa8Unp1osr0tO@G2VDC3rK9PTPPTp08Q6Qlp68pVt/1IbT15slV26jtb5QNHscsHtvXDD7atqZWKdvbDD6pNThWlVlXOPiq/SYXWD6Dcav3RwQ@fpIJUuGiV4DL4vVTa2zvQ8ZrqRmlfKnxqAEyjO5uRUqPdMFotvdtqS4UbqTCd4eDmtPGaj2s/zxGUarvTl/Bo6N12fPry6PDsqFxp6IXK85Ny5ezN04INL7XFG3ZV4e310eHzkzfn5YoY8pcXb4/enB4fPvM8L077/bQfjbqtg4OSAbxtn9RPDoxWFxiZ/lRqlZpZlpEPF1tgtM9b0zem3gD6L6XCaw6tdzSA/SoV2oW2ul/Zr1i@dWVN7Uv78lV0svw9OYEOb2p9jhJrZI3svm3bU4u9sa6n1rUVRCd2H54MfqwAmp41mFpDK7RC276F5/7f4CR6dRIBqgiGZVMrQ6zWAJ7Dk5NXgGwAhD/Dj2dZFvA3ta7g1/Jtfn28sCxNgky7W6vHlfpvbaynkNput82mXtaVSVnptJWuUzDTTscURidXwG6weza7uHh@eH54cWGi2gqFaaNYOijpB3A1W6VG/tgv9FsoNJCkpKiQEMcdxaFN6vAtdxEPhNp2t1S8oXvjGQaNLXtL4/5esxxn65DkL9vwkjd3HIel1OVcOIpgS1XZFfVV2e5MKwNSkTVM5nbB7exqo6HWa1qrVa/Ba30HvMLCzm3to73oqmhRIitTOUoUcjMTP@rNrKHyS8MfTcOPGhGPlnajNgAGgDT@KgYA2OTdu3f4925yNREt3hDf3i06V194A66re8auNyARJyNKlMKsgDE0JNs1DfIopm3X1Z3Sbv7TfKQB93JVqQL3siLNFda0CzhZqWA4r2W7Aj2gPge38pHPDB@SlequJMMlNXts6IVSo3UT9iXYYvYgeZuQJxZkfD4eF0WDwSOJeqJrRCFrZ7C3SZnvY56Mi/QkSvz@BBYOhOOVGVj98CHXgYE0ZXAFp5SNGZuMxxO2uJ556R79/JnGsMaajoHLS6Wyu1Pb2a1Wdso7uzvbNbteq5XtStl@svNk1yrblr1j13dqu3Z5Z3u3ur29vQu9td0n5pZU6LMB1i7GO0Su7nQsefElJimsZdFAiRXd3h/vyPUnsEGvPgEIWPHwVLSB58eRMWpJePZPVDABdBQwZc2ZAW5RRKnbUmEm9fFMYnvXwYA2a7SkooJjlKpU0KvRdlQoFosQ/c5bclU@MVKpyUCuIOiCjIML6fRrVLO/hT87hb1YqW4r1U6zIOzbfqIVWpUnRkqvC13xjajb8LFb4F5RsQtk6v1f/UYpGUz4tbDZNQteaW14n1wFMD9Cd37sD4de5cdPXyFhIopCKjVC7Doq@ZveEL8NuL1/diImLtdrslZIP158vKiAAezukuRyD3ZNCaZuHAQym/quTB6TFLvwv4m/1gu/A/YHcjDoXSQjAwbr9DjYlI0cJt4ripvecJGRQOPVGJKfhXkQtA/f66GB3PombGb1E//nYvgmIV9oGCo2IAa6Zb4TJ1s8HnY1cjOv36jYiyUEbVFxSFg2TkJiOaIyhCg8Z9EEKmjQpIkAvEwAYU/1mrZDvAYigyfkLDkFvOYjSk1s@ixUORdeV3Ok1VIK56QFo1d4WRlfKgnwmWBLzMcN@mLaom/xCuwFWDB21Xy0dgegbXUBRulYSj7NPzINyKzVBYYy@dPTuDMe0jNtPifOwrIz/75UxUzaysqBI@G0t2JH@kV1tRtMG51vwePH7se4HXQdLWhm@CyVAmcmXaqeANnKmkFTt50YmHWydqnkdZuB9osac@aDpgXAQBsxp9rNQtNhM1dXqpW/tEP9W9gtH7fDkt0tj8tbH5pfyrRplafwB2Ir@@XfQHhzUapZ80spdGgD/jCDvSWJuJmWqHO7wgVDLlW/@aVNu01Lc3wYWCodw2SAz7Ttl0pdDYj70Lk@0PEfP6YlvzV1fF3XEOpjdf@4nUGjW2ri@55KG9P9L@0xjN9T4dkEMr4GzMO42zoAfMCfAzIW6luyLnicIntTYC9oNrc@7G992Go@evSlPdWDblmIf89aKh6ZnyLzqzaibn1YNSwuEl5AVuWfvL2fjK2UyGWwPhByOV4ZKTjc@gA98dIbZv8D)

### Rundown

This program prints 70 in Commercial, 69 in rk-lang, 68 in Python, 67 in C11, 66 in Surface, 65 in ALGOL 68, 64 in Agony, 63 in Brian & Chuck, 62 in Grass, 61 in S.I.L.O.S, 60 in Moorhens 2.0, 59 in Tcl, 58 in Ksh, 57 in Wise, 56 in dc, 55 in Brain-Flak Classic, 54 in Zsh, 53 in Shove, 52 in COW, 51 in Assembly, 50 in Bash, 49 in Octave, 48 in Deadfish~, 47 in Lily, 46 in Cubix, 45 in PicoLisp, 44 in alphuck, 43 in reticular, 42 in evil, 41 in brainfuck, 40 in Minimal-2D, 39 in CoffeeScript, 38 in C, 37 in C++, 36 in Labyrinth, 35 in INTERCAL, 34 in Rail, 33 in Incident, 32 in Whirl, 31 in Modular SNUSP, 30 in Whitespace, 29 in Trigger, 28 in Brain-Flak, 27 in Perl 6, 26 in 05AB1E, 25 in Pip, 24 in Thutu, 23 in Hexagony, 22 in Underload, 21 in Nim, 20 in Prelude, 19 in Reng, 18 in Cardinal, 17 in Julia, 16 in Pyth, 15 in Haystack, 14 in Turtlèd, 13 in Ruby, 12 in Fission, 11 in Befunge-98, 10 in Befunge-93, 9 in Perl 5, 8 in Retina, 7 in Japt, 6 in SMBF, 5 in Python 2, 4 in ><>, 3 in Minkolang, 2 in V/Vim, and 1 in Python 3.

### Verification

Most languages can be tested with the test driver above, but 6 languages have to be tested locally.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 via manual balancing of tokens.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 locally, [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are n unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program. **not checked, can someone verify this?**
- Moorhens 2.0 can be tested to output 60 using [this interpreter](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/commit/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 using [this interpreter](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip) **not checked yet**

### Explanation

#### Commercial

Commercial has an unusual and obnoxiously strict syntax meant to sound like an infomercial. However, it also completely ignores anything that doesn't fit its syntax, which meant I just had to find a place where the other languages wouldn't notice it.

The Commercial code is this:

```
[var] now [value] dollar off!
[var] has been selling out worldwide!
```

The intervening lines were for Moorhens, and the variable name was constructed to help with some Incident tokens.

#### Moorhens 2.0

Commercial's code looks like this to Moorhens:
    jump reverse
    decrement roll increment push

So I had to add some words to work around that. That also caused a few minor blips with Incident, which is why both `ha` and `are` are used for Pop operations now. Currently, our Moorhens code looks like this:

```
duplicate ifJump pop jump reverse jump decrement roll increment push jump pop roll pop push noop long-line-of-increments reverse
```

(this might be a good thing to work into the test driver)

Also, because I'll lose this list if I don't add it here, here's a handful of short words I found for some operations:

- jump = `ai`, `ar`, `od`, `re`, `so`
- roll = `at`, `alb`, `om`, `ox`, `to`
- pop = `ha`, `my`, `pe`

(`int` would be a jump, which would have been super helpful for an incitent issue, but it's sadly not in the Moorhens dictionary :(, oh well)

#### Grass

I have no clue how Grass works, but it cares about `w`, `W`, and `v`. I *had* to add 3 w's. So I begged for help in chat and @WheatWizard came to the rescue. No clue what he did, but it works!

#### alphuck

Commercial adds a couple `s` that needed to be preceded by `p`, so I threw a `p` into my Commercial variable name.

#### rk

I golfed the rk a little bit, which led to the `os` that Incident and Moorhens needed being added back to the main Moorhens line where the `ax` used to be (both are reverse commands).

#### Incident

`ut` had to be detokenized, as did `b␠`. Commercial's variable name handles both of these. Eventually, `ha` and `ha␠` both gave me issues, which is how `my` came into play in the Moorhens code. Finally, `"6` and `"3` needed to be detokenized. The `"6` is handled just after the Commercial line since I knew that was a safe spot to put mostly arbitrary text (and because I had issues with `"␠` when I tried to inline that into rk). The `"3` is handled in what used to be `((("'3)3)3)"'`; I don't recall how that got added or what cares about it, but I needed to detokenize both `"3` and `)3`, so it became `((("3'3)))"'`.

#### General golfing

I found a stray space near the end of the program somewhere that I cleaned up, and I also found what must have been a Prelude-pleasing space near the end of the now-longest line that was safely removed.

Answer (score 7):

## 89. gnuplot, 2571 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.arxxxxx4O6O@
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO   /"78"oo@0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw  (([5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)';
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()] )}{\';       a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin

;print 89;exit#s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");"eg_0 ' ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#yxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}              @:8:8\\
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3   \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003646 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2657 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTtdd9pIls/R2X/QL2WJjiRAX2BsjADbnTiz6em0vbGTzAkQR4gCFAuJSMLgEHLmdffsw7zPyz7O/5jX@RXzR3rvrZIAG2ynz@6es7ItlapuVd2vuvdWXbnrxMPffpPwImehfzPww4QkNE5IL/KuaaSTn27IkePFlVJZEBhUFPYmrhcMSDKkxAvGk4T0PZ/GguskpEnG6Sg6FohEIur0OJjQDyOCXcjoyiceccdj0vWdoe4S3wPYF2YV4ONwhDAJjcYRhXtMAkp7JB5T1@t7LpuL0FlCg9gLg1gnnntFpp7vkx71ocMKAbcIg5FJvFbFp9OFXigQuNzxHXSXbzkKMAHNSKZjJ2Ikh2TM6M8on0bOeAxIChI5B8QTb0Rj4iVyTKgTe8hH6BLToMe4NV5yOCROsE4lufYc4gC@k4iNHdMoAfJ0Ni4Z0ojCkA5OPoicEVGmkZcAC5CZx@SMOhG5iChVYRYQAo1dZwx43JoSJgtxhgQJ0Zmw6nX55PSFDELjPXRnnAhSVL74t58Fh@gNkru04a8hirZw8utzMs@1sQxYwGAg2HGkOCppfCOx0W5T@JtZXWMQLQQYVQCu@MQIx4nhaGNAUEsAQcPBIpa065I@9tcmJvU7slhTJQ7VA2mQlwF5W2SUuZMoooDHiqnOFRDth8EA@AnERpMA@RGQPRNE4IZBLy4Seg1cCwMuo3DKOHwx9EBoMYrE6QKDHBd5z5cBYygsBNC9lKPZvHHoTxgc9IwTVEDgCnTFEV/2yVvSdzwfu0A7DsWxjmg88RPsMwl6KPmRF9CeTjI03LCHQKPwGqZzYFBWAStntLbeGFIADIIIGanY9M@//LU3GMA4x64bRr1UXd@SXuhORoCww5B1QBVRYcPA8RlaAFfE2Xl3mODa8b2ek@D0wU06BUOCzToNJ36PhDBhNPVgaQ2da1iO/T51E8qVPJwkgGORjJwrbiU8rrlA@MjpgmDZBGxuRrZGjp6BlFzKVUYbTZJ@lWjjEyLHxgflsKYc7rQp4Kbqaj5nGAMb9E3Psyp4kx9SnLfHK3mi9lx4Ia4jfzycgNWAliAegz2JkJmuA@TEaFYSsHxF0mWMZrYIVJ0t0imVI0q6sLIzwpiOcB3A/hqu3HSElUwzuNsqRntrGgbaCUqWxBtmwg@nMDHDDc0n6HSAkzsDB6ZKUoKOOUF8RlZzm7SrADQdR@tSUtW6HkgH9QCMTSqMNRoBvFziMDAal97aohg5NzCKy430SpLE64OQR6C30Q1xKS4GWBWUWzqcZMIUI/ZAj8I@MbVSpfKI8JPIONbeg/X4YjwoYyT@jpiPSZ9Oie8Eg4kzAEUOA@jiuC4dJ@kKAkriBNbIXUPIKrXUquvxUMgd3Z2bWbfU3q/NgdaHSy@10Q6qPTBqBKzWfFjlxIkGbCWSnhfBevFv7s4OANd3Jhc/IsgtBD6K96CQuSZQMjqj7iSB5QaKPB167hB0F7EL@ILl1vHu9FC1PjuYHK2/nBqRsZpPS4JuLKsQjXuH0FCim@OA1cehmrcqmPDXKx4e2YlHWwYOlyiChVqr1Q1HB91LmQb@/BxjCTB/mfNmK2sZYCz5CQz@GR1TRD9PQGCgz94gQBAnWDr@NcvoxYEMrsKLPeA6unDU9YuXp@gP3lEexQDfuS9bN@YhxDTQPXXR2JAJQaDuMCRaQOQUB0VkHvUToGXEkcsK2loYIao68ElBfrGmbKBPPDq761BJcxOOTSkXSUsUO0XwYX4MKhRMfB9eJgFbYgpV56BrLo1jHRYM8FbHeASwEwtUXdwGTIZROCV0odrytul@p0CeTbre7P@hRFzEi9@BqjUxsKrvkcMGYCYIUUxZtwHBePcsHKGdJ@8YxYjvTxH4hj74A2F8kwzB0mkuEZ1GOKaA0i1LIgOeEJ4rqs1COlnWP4VeoMzlnZ0duSY35SKUDqFUx9IhlgpQOmQljZUQTscS61FkJWxtsR5Y15EXrWzkmdpB0c4wbv3ijRWnVauVO0WnZaXPEj5VcCbgOwBawweMI6uNBhZVVWxOgVC92xc4@RcgnF8g5CO/eOiJ@xAgrrYOwnKytiByZpRv21Jx1VLi0eq1MQL26eOb7VGEuD4U6wAB3FWIOroqXZq6Vbk1BOx4Nnv2vXjIbrdAN9DabGG941G3z25bAGppGAAxBe6SkC/MlGEkEoag@VMGNgqDkKMC/PICx3jNHjp4j2343DbSt5DpUljzA2p0vQDLj4BpB1UG2e92vftAgS@IevbcAhZNutvYBuHZcMOPk1uMTyZR4tNe@vzHn3sggE3xDJ2bGAL6q2XhEviGotL690or7Yov7LZdsp8mPmz3HhnDdTCId/xlYftYNfKagvqDZAO2ywNMfaANIxwwdZv6DUvDn/Ro9tw@KOPh7XCA9w68EZMcPDG2YZbnnu53ghneHzc9kR86PYNvRD26EiVnOp05gzC4Mda8mh51vwPHLN4gq51nMpwkE37HzeZjQvPG@PfQYkwhzYrTtagRxk7Xu4eDiMTefUrL1wKaaa3vO1e8eInF7aRyYiJvADvb7HkfGER7EJCPHZcaU/a4134Ek3jMhMlKD4wX@fx@H4gXuOBZg1XhPkAg02e336NyTBFcWAeIKh72aGss8u4w1Xe6N@jKhr9ff3DCQaFANLAdDbdQMMtEC1d7sdWx0nh8f3/XTfsfHGzvzU@g2ABuCNtm@pg/AqfijRxfK/XWivfa18z1r0rbzI9z7UBQ4DsxKEiSspleg1jY7SGlRT/hTnwnWpUeUNkVOtmW@75d26rP2HND30s1M3vZMkGAYd7dkGg1DJ4ostuqK76lJvM5RD3oeL89aDdDN8HN0j2q8x0Wie9TcCe4pgt6eB@73HCKf/cu2GF4Tfl9uwv6shWr77A4ms@UAWLtze499zENxXMgdttuCa@2YpW4/tb6GnkVhhFsVGNS0s0HxbNVjWPPD2Nyzu4P8QK26HHM79sVeJ1tnhNo7pAvq2V5e7etSDGPRo7Z/R7hOv4g9PeqA8OB270aMIn6aNjT5/cataVRsqxHjdIyfAkDK33ea82v4Pcx5cADEDDfHsYxy@J2RbnXgqUR//0EQpiPB17biXthVpeaFcX0QZWqkePIHU6dmwehHvMc97E58xw1PKxngfD/bJrdh6fpfZ@V2hh2/@Fhb4n3yqdgptl9Q6ikZFq/s4dlmt9vs/r@hE7oVhty2v1EQXG@Oyh@ECkzJaNGvlz5D475XWijF8e3B22O43uwzh@NYWrkDILos/CRDUCNDILJmGWB7odi2@nXLGeyPMSMi2myB@q8KD3aj5f5M@ll4EaUHWlmhzREwoPWyQgigySMdMLgFMUpFFRV4J3Q0wwCAMugWAYDD5F5ciQm4PITBuv1SatFcvNZzaxZC9IgYk0knQ4flR1nnszGLPXwmndt5ZxOIydrmpyT20GNmDIDpT4s/K2gzi24vsceHM8V6SRwRuzcGssZpTY/HAd/jBmRoRP0YC/0JvDY@ZMbRvyIl@cRLnCj@fe/9dJE0YACkSMvBikPAkxuhiM6DKeHfN509uPx2MFEE44B4bfPT6i0Z8cknnqJO@T5IQgX3ry4qKaH@2myFV7OcBO0hgUXKjT1AQcn4ULj2PRCyrUinXjZKyMKYrDJKCBTr5cMYx2ca@BSljzIDrQBkwjBgiQKUauK5CXpUdwLsAO2TxOQrR@GV@xcDzH5@994SgMaPVQhLGfTsxzb2owE1oTF8giuG04A62yQLzQKUxAFmQyR5AQ4cgM6TXm9Styhw3ItoIlalmnAaXi24dnxOdFOiIw5Ykw82F5fyR2//sPbltlpfCMjg/7jzwaedTK@iT9q@1YsFkkGYi9Qr9abTWhetcpEzM3ElCzMRrLk21Kp@GoiCpaZuLLMwYglMpne0SnLHLD0UICBMmYIgxjWB7yqbGi@aBo5ZeJ7Iy8h2nlCKphIp8ASKPHUJ8HUNJ6CY5fcjHwlQ9QVzSVWxYQ3zhAfEy@jxk/ZMU15/TjNeE67E7b1vC7ppXKDkZO7bNSbrBTRXoipudaH9rRjxBlX2u3Zj2ZpBmwLIwB/auDKOfn1@TynN82vX2PwtaK4kG123InLOzc/e3l2cn5xfPHmHNi44FRKL8Jo5KxMBCrB2IcgaBj6LNcJ/Ig8Gj9uNp4wuyE8SQEVheQcUgfXQ8BCPVkalpStoibmeJG3MUuybLvTmJqPvkdSU0fOmLRTwcrxupkrZgqAzIM1OQG7miEPijPfYq4YOSJpAEEaEMTAlwgv37YRdruVwXOGH@I7MD0lYx2KkbqC2g6EtHLgFG8Ow5HcSsTifwnzMfiRxzFHqMcwB2DhsdnXJn5x/PKXN69PNudemzaF2QBZasja5yUnMwhewQ72mYZjCjPTmzBNQWeGAez@kOdFHH9l2uJligM1qY@G2Ye1jYuCHQDFuLgJ2hGdHPsxGNJeDyxD9yZBwwIWlWc1lqkNUQIG6Es/VySigLBxYzMVCYZjCpsL9yPvnGNwbOR4Wza/TY1//uWvPIPfTqD872m5D@X/5OUPBjJoM@XLcVyyBtny9uUZicFbccJHzmyNJnQY6JC8AEJEbwQcvGYMQXCO7Ire1ThK6y3wE4QAzETLh8aOzUejjjJMknHNMNC/w16tr7MzYToDOYCt1GF3Y3ye4AcVYJ@NvcrermUAktp1NiDL0w3wnJIPqKo1UCHh2hs3PnZdUq/XiRi7jk8bezZnpJFzPpTFj0tEcwAr8FCgRaAPdFn1gLZm2k3JOQVLxa64CmVLJh0bvDyXCzgKhRUARMXqIOWHCJ4oTFmFKT86S5hRvclCHIgvgpCMkE/ss5psIA0G4mOrorChu6vzSMzDrGmzvi4G8R2CnSNYTdymOgQ05L@2aE4A5f/g5Vbb1L51tn0SstSd480vP5S7320gLeToPAjxfPoF4EqUklEqG9aeurZOxHQowBZXxVcYEtYBrCuXep/CcXz87OTlz6dn5xtfLjBI@S6YTORmvdDW9GKrsyzId3Q@Y@lPL4zzVz@9yBi5jlXadBerbYPfReyeyd7xk9/NqVjDxkSW@b0DszSl9oLthLYQsmw11gCf8WOqjVkVdb5oderNdiBtTP9122dFkp7HL4mg1I7ZR0Uy2WJgXmbn2RfhFajHA99LaAlCeF/Wv5zITsPxs4RS0@jRawPz6IK@OicXc0r9FrYq/7aD8yCbHuxEWpODnWiTrOZyhY0zx3VE@NFPuMTkVs8ls5HmU76zY59GOQEE9ZHncuiYGVe@/2Pf8cAO4GWy2jTARgR32mxvdMP2AbDMl2d4PY8d7zrRTUrBsuWcjjztIsMHF/0qWQ1GKIwS2H7EQ9/r2k6jNSPLVO5DeWw9HvteomACeabj/gqoUVQkwKr7FPPP9YNOmuwmWU66wNLaZxPg11k4Jqs97XOalV7DtoY8hy20BxpAyc@TEcD12eM1RQtPya@hBp2Bj3KGRAtmUVIa9FGvArPrQzrreQPwEopaBIPyo2WtEuKOWoC9qAw2lLPqD3g4uc6Y35XEX@OY03J0L@jRmSJPZbXWQe5AvTx9dy2r4oYOsC8J0s8Kenc/KcjWvpOki3CZjl9fOFnAApOnCT1wIvihJ37CARsFD3T66I80CEBlFEB7BApCnAnQGanF7Hvj4vLbsDW78K9pfvCulziR534IvjBn2GxLYi/AIXxsk3bS7rcD9Ar2jfGDoRv2XMn5jRsDHLnaVHLDhlUo5wuFXJBXcgG6sqdPcSezyIGnvNRFXZwBkJbzVRv4CZ61kQvsnFNXcr1GKc96wGuhoM6hw7fY0Oc5Z2HknoJjKkJNxLVDycUqisPUdWsB@KGEckZx5IznikjEGX5ih9PnvEIBcdBzl4jAN6N9XmBmqn1usL2TnQZIxmCUqfEtZfjtN8nag1j9cK@shIel8k5eItKRaOTbz9@/f3Ztyy2nX9I/d86uzs7@pLYVWXp2Klq7ok3yhiAZefPrvmF8/PgRQgfSaupNvaO2NLnTUpr7@3m7uFfNF4@Klly0JeJbpmWpSqmknrd3A/sJXIp1JsuVsnz@Ab8ROdyBH/YL1/IV7zusJq1mIJvXjkqUzzNBaj4BnSnv7Rw9AZRogV212hERpG@CJEgf6x8FCQIhqdnsLBaFeqte15vNWVPrNFuCNBek2UKQSiJyIC9IjVn9NRuh9bzJhyp8Bm7@As@61mmNz345OT4/KZbqmlR6cfysWDp/85NkwVtl9YqNZXx9fXL8/PTNRbHEe/3h5duTN2dQ73neOO714l447DSPjgq6pmlHerMD@Mx@LDQLjSRJyPvLvO5EM7x2T/dOjwTpeXP2xtDqgMovgvSa9dLagFxbhb5fBakltZTD0mHJ9M1r07qyrl6Fp6vf01PUCnG/KobhEYB4M/NTGJlDc2j1LMuamfSNeWPezMxReGr1oEjhxxxB0TP7M3NgBmZgWbeGvP93dBq@Og1hqBC6JTMzwVHNPjwHp6evYLA@TPwJfjzTRFRn5jX8mr7Frg@Xpmq22wLsFjuVvXFp73OL2Z3KQadFZ17SEUlRbrfkji0ZcbttcEUXS6Cl2LxYXF4@P744vrw0cPs0q@cKRwXtCK5Gs1BPH4dSr4ks1Os7bUFWpu/evcO/d9PrKS@xAq97t2xcf2EFuK7v6Xu7gGecrUpnvlAJ/Dxpy7bM0VYUCl5TEa32rNQnJZE5owMwBVYZAn5lr6I2m3sVeN@rqppiYuuu@sGq19OmkhpGojwTw0gm8wX/UeaLusIuFX9UFSvTe1NVoFmtwNtsrszqSl3BOqjCXvNFE4sMbg6llqJ21MWC18FdUet8zKYKZGG4/3/0G8awNyWytJDQ/Adkt6LCZoKqu3tKtXCQ/jR2gBhFLMtloFGUHbnVOsqX8/u7rcNOvpNX6nk93252ZuuXKksEdCtTkYYlIfcESbdfi1ZJlFFlbDxCC32q@xDclw9sWcnfvarWQSFfOGrlDw74ZPn81x1VtgUJBhfhkkCtiELqzXp2nqCsjhbUJvzNScpgoi7moBBpGzgQJT0ba7dnpsng7W4jN5echc2GJwtxCc6Pz9nwimyzQ1NxLuacqGV1xIWYm3cX6GXzlsr8Y2XXtvO7vLxftcGsW/m0xYSWtAgNNHZctpzAkqMmycBiFYhqdOnACwSBay@pHjAgKRYgOOiC5KZk34Tgz/ediIT9/g6vhygHtocUvDz1fdxnY5A/DSO/N4XAc0eQYgrX6MyhE0qnk8mULq9nXlxzPn2C4HWMLghiE1PQcepS6aBaqR6US9Vi9aC6W7H2KpWiVSpa@9X9A7MI3qdq7VUrB1axuntQ3t3dPYDWysG@INGg5/UNA@y9JYqEFSACxq@d6vhdWKgPm@A@erSPR6tPZkpPfSL1lhWTKhHL1bbZNkUBPwVEwapztFAKiSFWDftEMYsTWK6Vw0lV3NsXa3l4iodiGYpMYDOFmDJIVpTboqi2DjqH4n4FxquBW9Tkp9YhEfcPxJq4vw@Vqi3SwaVJZCLaC0A2Y8KSDAJmTNcJ/GmagO3c8SviPpgT2QYwm3f5l7U@0VUtTpwIN0kMHPYQewciVgNIqrPNSjdfK1pa8YgPSfYsQVoIPfzgYvfARvcJJqXeFHIyMkIuC5JWDndDKZfLgdO9aIpl8VSvG6knbRrMjbbRs6L30jPH3BQiige0PfzvIW4VqxXVxspYaEC9YOOKEqUbvoZv0I21@ZD1bxJLppOz@fLgLv26uPYKkFKc2jn7kqwF6@zbr54/r5a1JotEISJeEPD@C3LrOqpVa1VYZlL8NaxY34Kfbak2lsu7chmdbUPiCFr7qtQs7euxcyN10lSQsruvEnhji6hkSf0pu5YeY8N/rJW2vE@vRywIAUyqP/QGA6/0w6uPX2EzKsuEWLm9b1qd/9bh9uyUi0gR9yqiKsVx/OHywyUEQBUilioiIQUDQjjD@FMJ1s3BwV51TxJ@M4yHNrPQuozF@xTC1MloWzB@HHmvHDw9DJYBORReTWDXtlxXBBcWbnOGzdt1bLHdqmL/fgZ1AuKFaqVgwYkGbpEdaZI8fjjY6qhknh2HK9iKJ7Lq8gA3oskkCohp84N2HMKzl0WYBVcqaSAAUxlwsIrXsGzi1XEweELIns6AV9aj0MAibhUZFl5HtYX1k2mGSRN6r@Gy1r9Q4OALjhanxx31ONm8bfkK6I0wg@cqaW/1DkDL7ACM3DbllMzvIQP2ZMpyhCL53WTc6Q@7EzWjiaGwakzrV6JYCPmkOLIFJDs/toU/Kq46x12T/W309Kn7YdwadWx11EjwWSiM7IVwpXgcJJ80Rg3NsseArJ20CgWv0xipf1TGDPlRwwRgmBtHjtX5UtJBIxVXrBa/tALtW9ApvmgFBatTnBTz7xtfik7DLM7gD9hW9IufgXkZK5Wk8aUQ2E4d/nADd4sT40ZccOzbCQPocqX4jS8tp9MwVduHjoXCCyAG8IxbfqHQUWFyHxo3O9r@06dOwW/ObF/TVIT6UD580Uqg0Ck08L2mOPXZ4ZfWBPrXFHg2YBpfBeSh320ZwHiAnw085uJboc5xnCF6M0Bv1Gjk3x/m3@cbOztfWjNt1Cly9tfMleAR@Rkiv64jSv79umIxlrCoRRF/9Go/6vmYiEXQPmBycbzWk2OYfw8t49VqWPw3)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- gnuplot. 89 [local](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html)

### Explanation

#### gnuplot

The intended purpose of gnuplot is plotting graphs, but we aren't doing any of that today. The main feature of gnuplot we use to work it into the polyglot is that it has `#` line comments that can be extended onto the next line via a backslash line continuation.

The code that does the work is.

```
;print 89;exit#s
```

This consists of an empty statement terminated by `;` to prevent S.I.L.O.S recognising the print statement,the print statement, the exit command (which could be equivalently replaced with quit, but I used exit to help appease incident), and a comment containing an s to close the alphuck loop opened by the p.

All the lines before this line that do not start with `#` need to be made part of a comment via backslash line continuations. Depending on the parity of a line (Retina doesn't like backslashes at the end of a line unless they are escaped by another backslash on one of its parsers) and whether the line is visible to the scripting languages this is achieved by appending one of `\`, `\\`, `#\` or `#\\`. There are two minor exception to this: tcl has similar behaviour with regards to using backslashes to continue comments onto the next line, this is fixed by using a double backslash on the line just before the tcl code as the first backslash escapes the second backslash for tcl (I think, either way it made the code work). The other minor exception was a `#\\` added on a line by itself. Some of the `x` at the end of the longest line were removed to keep the end of that line at the correct length for Klein.

#### SNUSP

Because the backslash that was now added at the end of the SNUSP is a reflector a `!` was added to jump over it.

#### Incident

For some reason I had extra tokens coming out the wazoo. The tab in the C main method brackets was changed back to being a space. The `<><` in the Brain-Flak just before the shell scripts was shifted one space right to avoid `(<` being a token. The continuation backslash for gnuplot on the long line has a space before it to prevent `\` from being a token. One of the `x` in the detokenizing section near the Archway was changed to a `y` to prevent `y"` from being a token. I think there was one more change I made for Incident but I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 7):

## 94. [Emotinomicon](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Emotinomicon), 2763 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?24O6O@?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp
set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof( "(\"           ); print'(''72'')';end!"           ); main( ){puts("92" );return 0;}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

(Emojis broke something in the pretty printer of the test driver. I manually fixed the above code.)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003326 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2851 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbcttIds9G5Q/2pQVyDIAkbqQoUbxJGlva9ex4pFi@bJmkZRBskrBw4eAiUqbp2qdUJZWHrTylah@Sx/2Pfd2v2C/IH0zO6QZISqQkTyWpCiwCDfTp7nPrc@lu961o/MsvObzIeeDejNwgJjGNYjIInWsaauT7G3JkOVG1XBEEBhUGg8R2/BGJx5Q4/iSJydBxaSTYVkzaZJL2omGB5EhIrQEHE4ZBSLAJ8a5c4hB7MiF91xprNnEdgD01agAfBR7CxDSchBTuEfEpHZBoQm1n6NhsLEJnMfUjJ/AjjTj2FZk6rksG1IUGKwTsEnRGkmjtEx9OEwaBQOCyJ3fQXb7lKcD4NCOZTqyQkRyQCaM/o3waWpMJICnkyAUgHjsejYgTSxGhVuQgH6FJRP0B49ZkyeGAWP46leTasYgF@CYh6zuiYQzkaaxfMqYhhS4tHHwUWh6Rp6ETAwuQmcfknFoheR1SqsAoIAQa2dYE8Lg1JAwW4AgxEqIxYTWb0snZqQRC4y00axILubDy@h9/ECyitUj@sgG/lig2hJOfnpN5votlwAI6A8FOQtlSSOsrifRul8JvZvb1UbgQoFcBuOISPZjEuqVOAEE1BgR1C4tYUq/L2sRdG5g078hiTZU41ACkQV745G2JUWYnYUgBjxVTrSsg2g38EfATiA0TH/nhkz0DRGAH/iAqEXoNXAt8LqNgyjj8euyA0CIUidUHBlk28p5PA8ZQmAigeylHs3GjwE0YHLSMYlRA4Ao0xR5fDMlbMrQcF5tAPXbFsQ5plLgxtkn8AUrec3w60EiGhh0MEMgLrmE4CzplH2DmeGvzjSEFwCCIgJGKVX//058HoxH0c2zbQThI1fUtGQR24gHCFkPWAlVEhQ18y2VoAVwJR@fNYYBry3UGVozD@zfpEAwJNuo0SNwBCWDAcOrA1Bpb1zAdh0Nqx5QreZDEgGOJeNYVtxIO11wg3LP6IFg2ABubka2So2cgJZtylVG9JB7WiDo5IVKkf5AP6/LhTpcCboqmFPK6PmqAvmkF9gnepIcU5@3xSp6oPa@dAOeROxknYDWgxo8mYE9CZKZtATkRmpUYLF@J9BmjmS0CVWeTdEqlkJI@zOyMMKYjXAewvYozN@1hJdMM7raK0cGahoF2gpLF0YaZcIMpDMxwQ/MJOu3j4NbIgqHilKBjThAfkX25TdqVD5qOvfUpqal9B6SDegDGJhXGGo0AXilzGOiNS29tUnjWDfRicyO9kiRxhiBkD/Q2vCE2xckAs4JyS4eDJEwxIgf0KBgSQy1Xq48IPw71Y/U9WI/P@oMyRuLviPmYDOmUuJY/SqwRKHLgQxPLtukkTmcQUBLFMEfuGkL2UU2tuhaNhfzR3bGZdUvt/doYaH249FIbbaHaA6M8YLXqwiwnVjhiM5EMnBDmi3tzd3QAuL4zuPgRQW4h8FG8B4XMNYGS0Rm1kximGyjydOzYY9BdxM7nE5Zbx7vDw6f10cHkqMPl0IiM2X5aFjR9@QnRuLcLFSW62Q9YfeyqfesDE/76h4d7tiJvS8fBEkWwUGtfNd3SQPdSpoE/v8BYAsxf5rzZzFoGGEt@AoN/QMcU0p8TEBjoszPyEcTyl45/zTI6kS@Bq3AiB7iOLhx1/fWLM/QH7yiPYoDv3JetG/MAYhponrporMiEIFB7HBDVJ1KKgywyj/oJ0NKj0GYFdS2MEBUN@CQjv1hV1tEnHp3ddaikvQnHhpRKpCOKvRL4MDcCFfIT14WXxGdTTKbKHHTNplGkwYQB3moYjwB2YpEqi9uA8TgMpoQulIa0bbhfKZBnSd@Z/T@UiI148TtQtSYG9ulb5LABmAlCFFPWbUAw3j0LPLTz5B2jGPH9PgTfMAR/IExu4jFYOtUmotUKJhRQumVJJMATwnNZabCQTpK0T4Hjy3NpZ2dHqkttqQSlQyg1sXSIpSKUDllJZSWE07DEWpRYCWs7rAV@60mLTtbzTOmhaGcYt352JrLVqdcrvZLVMdNnGZ8KOBPwHQCt4gP6kZRWC4uKIranQKjWHwqc/NcgnB8h5CM/OuiJhxAgrlIHYTlYVxA5Myq3bam4qinzaPVa94B92uRmexQhrnfFGkAAdxWgjq5Kl4ZmVm91ARnPZsuhE43Z7RboBlqbNax15PWH7LYFoJ6GARBTYJaEfGGmDCORIADNnzIwL/ADjgrwy/Et/RV7aOA9tuFz20jfQqZPYc6PqN53fCw/AqYe1BjksN937gMFviDq2XMLWJj0t7ENwrPxhh8ntxgfJ2Hs0kH6/NsfByCATfGMrZsIAvqrZeES@IaiUof3Sittii/stl2ynxIX0r1H@rAtDOItd1nY3ledvKKg/iBZn2V5gKkLtGGEA6ZuU79harjJgGbP7Z0yHt4OB3hr3/GY5OCJsQ2zPPc0vxPM8PaY9IRuYA10nog6dCVKznQ6s0aBf6OveTUt7H8Djlm8QVaZZzxO4oTfMdl8TGjOBH8PTcYU0qhafZPqQWT1nXs4iEjs3ae0fC6gmVaHrnXFi5dY3E4qJyZ0RpDZZs/7wCDag4B8YtlUn7LHvfbDT6IJEyYrPdBf6PL7fSCOb4Nn9VeF@wCBTJfdfo3KMUWwYR4gqrjYo66xyLnDVNfq36ArG/96/cEBR8UiUcF2tOxi0agQNVjlYqtlpcnk/va2nbY/ONjemq9AsQ7sANJm@pg/AqfieJarlgdrxXvta@b6V6Vt5se6tiAocK0IFCRO2UyvQSzs9pDSop@wE9cKV6UHVHaFTpZy35e1rdpMHDtwnVQzs5ctA/gY5t0NiVbd4Ioiu62a4ltqMp9D1IOO9@uDdjOwY0yW7lGdb7BIPE/BTHBNF7TgPnbZwRR/907YcXBN@X27C/q8FatvsDiqy5QBYu3N5gP7MQ3FdSB2224Jr7ZiFdvu1u918jIIQkhUI1LWjAfFs1WNI8cNInLB7g/xAlL0KOL37Qq8zjbH8lV7zKfVsry92VakmEcjx@x@j3AtdxS4e7WRbsHtXg1IwiEa9vT5rUZtaZRM81GjtAxfAt9Mn/da8yv4e0w5cAEEzLeDccyyuF1R7rVgacR/P4EQ5uOC13biTo3aUrPCiD6oUnVyHNrjqXXzINRjnuM@Nmeeo46L9SwQ/p8Ns/vwMINvs1Ib3e4/3O0t8V65FMw0u28IlZQN81e2MA3j223W0E1oQrfakLP@JwqK881B8YNIGSkZdfL5yn2wz29CG704vj1ocyzXgXn@aAxTJ@cQRJ8HjyQAIz@Z3JLlevaQ@K8emRPPgmDw6zV1aXVqj4dCdXJB40ewOPECSE4DD0IC/yFQtizwiu39LBdjo1K6aQXfnDDdooiW@4C5F74dUrY0my02kRwuGCceRDhxEGqEwcmyVSwqisAboccc@QCWQbGdGFwM55s8EYHQJWawzpB0OiQ/n9WNurkgLSLWRdLr8V7ZsuzJbMK2UF7xpp281WvlJVWV8lLXrxNDYqDUBQO2FdS6BTd02IPjuSKd@JbH1t@xnFHa4Iv8EFfgzs7Y8geQ073xHbaOZgchX6rm@yGvMWH@618G6YbXiAKRnhOBto583KQNPDoOpod83HT048nEwg0z7APSCJevtKnPjkk0dWJ7zPe5IOx5c/q6lm5SpJvG8HKOydwaFlyoUDUEHKyYC41jMwgo14p04GWrjCiIJRPPJ1NnEI8jDYIE36ZsEyRbmAdMQgTz4zBArSqRF2RAMadhC4WfEpCtGwRXbH0SMfnrX/jWDFQ6qEJYzoZne4VrIxKY2ybbD7HtIAGss04@0zBIQWRkMkTECXDkBnSa8u8KsccW2zMCTVSzHRMchu@aPDu@IOoJkXCvGzdQGs5Qzh@/@u3bjtFrfSWeTv/2Rx3XbBnfxO/UfTMSSyQDaSxQr9arDahe1UpEzM/ElCzcVWWbiEul4rOJyFhm4sp2QDy2Icv0jk7ZDgjb5vIx4MedTj@C@QGvCuuaT5pWXk5cx3Niol7EpIoHAsAyWFDiW7gEt9hxNR@b5GfkCxmjrqg2MasGvHGGuLiB5LW@z5abKuvLgvpz2k9YCn1d1sqVFiMnf9lqtlkppIMAtxg7H7rTnh5lXOl2Z98Z5RmwLQgB/KmOM@fkp@fzvNY2vnyJIGYQxYXUYMu2OL3z8/MX5ycXr49fv7kANi44lbnTIPSslYlAJZi4EMyNA5ft2QI/QodGj5uNJ8xuCE9SQFkmeYs0wYUSsFBPloYlZauoinle5HXMkizr7lSm5mPokNTUkXMm7VSwUrRu5kqZAiDzYE4mYFcz5EFx5lvMFSNHJC0gSAWCGPgS4eXbNsJu1zJ4zvBDfAemp2SsQzFSV1DbgZBWDpzizWE4kluJWPwvYT4BP/I45gj1GOYALDw2@trAp8cvfnzz6mRz7LVhU5gNkKWGrB2TOZlBEA52cMg0HLdiM70J0q30zDCA3R/z/R3LXZm2aLlVg5o0RMPswtzGScEWsiKc3ATtiEaO3QgM6WAAlqF/E6NhAYvKd2eWWzRiDhigLf1ciYgCwkatzS1VMBxTCFfsj7xxnsGxnqNtpxK6VP/7n/7MTyJ0Yyj/c1oeQvlfefmDjgza3LrmOC5Zg2x5@@KcROCtOOGeNVujCR0GOiTHh1DX8YCD14whCM6RXdG76kfuvAV@ghCAmWj50Nix8WjYk8dxPKnrOvp3yDmHGlvbpjOQA9hKDbI0/ecED4aAfdb3qnu7pg5IqtdZh2y/cYTrrbxDRamDCgnXzqT1sW@TZrNJxMi2XNraa3BG6nnrQ0X8uEQ0D7ACDwU6BNpAk1ULqGunzeS8VTQVbIqzUDIl0muAl@dyAUchswKAKPjZT/khgicKUlbh1iWdxcyo3mQhDsQXfkA85BM7HpR1pEJHvG9FFDZ0d7WuivtJa9qsrYtBfIdgFwhWF7epDgEN@c8tmuND@V94udM11K@9bUdblrpzvHmCRb57/gRpIUcXfoDr7KeAK5HLermim3vK2jwR064AW5wVX6BLmAcwr2zqfAom0fGzkxc/nJ1fbJzAYJDSXTCJSO1msatqpU5vWZDu6HzG0u9P9YuX359mjFzHKq26i9W2zu8ids9g7/gK9uZQrGJjINP41o7Zdqt6yjK6LYQsa/U1wGd8uW1jVFmZLzq9Zrvr5zaG/7LteFROK@CJKCh1I3Y4SiJbDMyLbF3@dXAF6vHAuQ81Rgjn8/oJkGxVH49XlNv6gF7reB5A0Fbr/WJebt7CVuFnVDgPsuHBTqRf8pBRt8lqLFvYWDtdR4Qnk8ESk1stl8xGms94ZseOeFk@BPWhY3PoiBlXnv@x80iQAbyIV0kDJCK4YsByoxuWB8A0X65FDhy2TG2FNykFy5oL6jnq6wwfnPSrTXcwQkEYQ/oRjV2n37BanRlZbkk/tB@vRRPXiWXcCJ9pmF8BNbKCBJhNl@I@evOgl27ak2xvvci2588T4Nd5MCGrnPY5zUqvIK0hzxPoHDSAkh8SD@CG7PGKooWn5KdAhcbARylDogOjyCkNmjeowujamM4Gzgi8hKyUwKB8Z5qrjX1LKUIuKoEN5az6LS6yrjPmVx1GWOOY1bE0xx/QmSxNJaXeQ@7Ad2n67lpSxA0dYCci0uMRg7tHI7K5b8XpJFweK1ifOFnAAoOnG5PgRPDAKh5FgUTBAZ0@@j31fVAZGdD2QEGIlQCdoVLKzk2Xlmfc1uzC79J9zrte4kSauwH4wrzeYClJYwEO4WOXdOPusOujV2jc6L/RNb0xl/Nu60YHR6605fy4ZRYrhWIx7xfkvI@u7OlTzGQWefCUl5qoiTMAUvOu0gB@gmdt5f1G3mrK@UGrXGAt4LVYVObQ4Guka/O8tdDzT8ExleBLyLVDzkcKisPQNHMB@KGE8nrJsyZzWSTiDI8K4vB5p1hEHLT8JSLwVe9eFJmZ6l7oLHdqpAGSPvIyNb6lDL/8kjP3IFY/3KvIwWG5slPIkdyRqBe6z9@/f3bdkDrWsKz93Du/Oj//g9KVpdyzM9HcFRukoAs5vWB82df1jx8/QuhAOm2trfWUjir1OnJ7f7/QKO3VCqWjkimVGjnimoZpKnK5rFx0d/2G4ziTaDCAXzDGs0TgPOsomidwyea5JFUr0sUHPANzuAP/2B9cy1e877Av6WcGsnntKET@eSbk2k9Alyp7O0dPAFVaZFe9fkSE3FchdyPkPjY/CjmIkHLtdm@xKDY7zabWbs/aaq/dEXJzITdbCLmyiKwpCLnWrPmKddF53uZ9FX8GNv8Iz6ba60zOfzw5vjgplZtqrnx6/KxUvnjzfc6Et@rqFSsr@Prq5Pj52ZvXpTJv9dsXb0/enMP3qNc@Oipqqqoeae0eYDH7rtgutuI4Ju8vCzA3nrdnb3S1CYP@KOReMUi1C2h0FYD/IuQ6uY58WN492zs7OiwbrnFtmFfm1cvgbPlHXp6dQYUzMz4FoTE2xubANM2ZQd8YN8bNzPCCM3MARQr/DA@KjjGcGSPDN3zTXO/ogT/vLHh5FkBXATSLZ0aMvRpDeI7Ozl5CZ0MY@BP8cwwDEZwZ1/BnuCa7PlxCXmV0u0IH1LRX3ZuU937uMLtTPeh16MyJeyIpSd2O1Gvk9Kjb1bmii2XQUqxeLC4vnx@/Pr681DF9mjXzxaOiegRXq11spo/D3KCN/NOaO11Bkqfv3r3D37vp9ZSXWOHdlLxLL3jTxf2aGARHKei71fPdFK7rezq5XSC3LlnuVHvzhaIoT7pSQ@KUyDIFRyqLZndWHpKyyPzTAVgHswI5gLxXVdrtvSq879UUVTawdlf5YDabaVVZCUJRmolBKJH5gv@T54umzC4F/ykKfkzvbUWGaqUKb7O5PGvKTRm/wSdsNV@0scjg5lDqyEpPWSz4N7jLSpP32VaAQMwA/o/@ggjSVSLlFjn0CD7ZrSqQX1Bld0@uFQ/Sf60dIEYWK1IFaBQlS@p0jgqVwv5u57BX6BXkZkErdNu92fqlSDkC@pZpTcvMIfeEnNZ4JZplUUItauCqWuBSzYV4v3LQkOTC3atmHhQLxaNO4eCAD1YofNlRoDX0LcKVA0UjMmm2m0vprxRBacNvTlL@QnkxB4XgdeBS5HS1rNudGQaDb/Rb@XnOWjRY92QhZtCpXrHuZanBllHFuZi3wo7ZExdift5foN8tmArzmNXdRqOwy8v7tQYYerOQ1hhQkxahgkaWzSYY2HZUJAk4rABRrT4dOb6QmwgNXFLk65eiKnJlJrUD1igXRQLED32Q5JTsGxAfuq4VkmA43OHfIRCCDJJCIEBdF1NxzAOmQegOphCb7gi5iMLlnVs0oXSaJFO6vJ45Ud369AniW3b913/8@z/B7y/w@zd8CojWDqnuZwVTeIlJ6oHJl@wd/AwlSPx/B8h5iT3GfRAnRpcHsZAhaEhIuXxQq9YOKuVaqXZQ262ae9VqySyXzP3a/oFRAm9XM/dq1QOzVNs9qOzu7h5AbfVgX8hRf@AMdR3ciCmKhBUg4sZTYk08Txdo4za4pQEdOj59QmbyQHmSG2QfSFIjYqXWNSDIxxOUIFaFzNEgyiSC0BgQl41SAqagepjUxL19sV6Ap3goVqDItGEmE0MCtRGlrigqnYPeobhfFevga1XpqXlIxP0DsS7u74tKQ6SjqijukfK@KL53cCeViI0FoJyxYkkMAeOpaQR@qipg/aTF0ZGJKHfFNWVU0v/ZJMmStF@WJEVqQCc7d0CQNiCNUyYelEX4GNI4CX1iNBZ89H9YGz68qkexFWKWx3qHJGjvQMTPANLkU6td7RfqJVMtHQlcGfdMIbcQBnjyZfeggW4eDGCzLeQlHF6qCDm1EuwGuXw@D8HB67ZYEc@0pp56/LbO3H0XIwD0vVoWQLSFkOIK8wD/Gxe34bUqoj8ikdCC70IDDYCYSy3ODXqSLu@y@TXHTjWQ8/ly5TE95l1/iTyx6hfsSF@nR5SvPznuvFZR2yyUhpB@QYA1i8nFwYf9D7UPL9@cvTk7ParX6jWwCrnoixJUza/@D41cfSJVdqUKhAqtHEfQ3Fdy7fK@Flk3uV66lyXv7isE3ticL5u5Ifq1pVvbdHtrpS3v02uPxUqASO03g9HIKf/m5ccvkExLEiFmfu@r2uR/Tbg9O@MSksW9qqiAtYg@XH64zAm5KhHLVdCVog4hqK7/oQzz8OBgr7aXE37R9YeScahd5hJDCmF24m1LJo5D56WFq5/@MqGAwssEss7lPCU4UTFNG7dvf2OT99Yn9t8A4ZuAeDGlxoIVjuwSW5IlBTzA2enBJM6W82WsxRVlZbkAvdR8vlGAXTiNZRFGwblGWgjANAaiAdlpmQ3iNLEzeELKkY6AV9ai2MIiproMC6enNIT1lXWGSRtar@Gy1r5Y5OALjhanx/YGnGxet3wF9DzcgbTltLVyB6Bj9ABG6hpSSua3kAE5pbzsoUR@NRl32kN2pWQ0MRRWlen3lSgWQiEueQ0ByS5MGsLvZVuZY9bX@Oo9fWp/mHS8XkPxWjE@i0UPzNaV7HCQQtzyWqrZmACyjbhTLDq9lqf8Xp4w5L0W2jgYG3uOlPlS0n4rFVeklD53fPWr3yuddvyi2SslpcL71ueS1TJKM/gB20pu6WdgXsZKOW59LvoNqwk/TEBvcQKsddFq3N7wgCZXstv63LF6LUNpuNCwWDwFYgDPqOMWiz0FBnehcrNhw3361Cq67VnDVVUFoT5UDk87MRR6xRa@12WrOTv83EmgfV2GZwuGcRVAHtrdlgH0B/g1gMdcfCvUOY4zRG8G6HmtVuH9YeF9obWz87kzU71eibO/bqwEj8jPEPl1HZEL79cVi7GExViy@J1T/04rREQsgfYBk0uTtZYcw8J7qJmsZsPivwE)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)

### Explanation

Emotinomicon is a language with emoji commands. 
The code is . Every emoji in this code takes 4 bytes in UTF-8, so 16 bytes total.
Note that you have to wait about 45 sec for online interpreter to finish.

#### Python 2

Python 2 doesn't like Unicode characters, even in comments. 
According to [pep-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), it can be fixed either with BOM (byte order mark) or by specifying encoding
with magic comment. BOM is not good for editing because it is invisible and also it breaks ><>, so I used special comment.
This comment must be on the first or second line and it must match regular expression `^[ \t\v]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)` (`?` seems redundant).
So the word `coding` may appear anywhere on the line after `#`.

I added `coding:utf8` to the second line. It broke deadfish~ because the word `coding` contains 4 deadfish~ commands. To fix it, I placed deadfish~ code (`iiipsddpsdoh`) before `coding`. `p`s in deadfish~ code are for alphuck. Space before `coding` is for what.

#### Underload

Underload broke, and enclosing emojis in parens didn't work. So I tried random positions for emojis until Underload got fixed.

#### V

VAbstraction cuts everything before `␛dgg`, so I decided to check how V would process entire file. If emojis are before `␛dgg` V works as expected (prints 2,
execution time about 5 minutes). However, strangely enough, if emojis are *after* `␛dgg` then VAbstraction passes, but V fails. So **do not put emojis after `␛dgg`**.

#### Alice

It was hard to find a place for Alice which doesn't break Underload. Again, parens didn't help.

#### Others

Cubix, prelude, incident as usual. Retina broke because I added Cubix code on odd line, fixed by moving Cubix further on even line (16).

Comment: Oh wow, you broke out the unicode.  This will really open up the possibilities,  until now we had believed it impossible to do so.

Comment: @Wheat Wizard I thought we just thought it would be hard.

Answer (score 7):

## 97. [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically)  [v1.3](//github.com/aaronryank/Cubically/releases/tag/v1.3), 2851 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8ââââ(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>â
# 36!@â`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?24O6O@?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))â\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppppðð¨ðð¨ð¬95ð¬ð¥â¡
ðð¢ðððððððð

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#defineâ x(d)â#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"eg5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof( "(\"           ); print'(''72'')';end!"           ); main( ){puts("92" );return 0;}
#if 0â
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>
reg end="";print(85);reg s
=end
;"""#"#xxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8âdggi2âM`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .003123 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2939 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbcttIds9G5Q/2pQVyDIAkbqQoUbxJGlva9ex4pFi@pEzSMgg2SVi4cABQpEzTtU@pSrIPm608pHYrmSRVqdqH/MW@7lfsF@wfTM7pBngRKclTSaoCi0ADfbr73PpcuttdKxr@@GMGL3IeuDcDN4hJTKOY9ELnmoYa@fqGHFlOVC6WBIFBhUFvbDv@gMRDShx/NI5J33FpJNhWTJpklPSiYYFkSEitHgcT@kFIsAnxrlziEHs0Il3XGmo2cR2APTUqhHrBBwdaRYGHkDENRyGFe0R8SnskGlHb6Ts2G5HQaUz9yAn8SCOOfUUmjuuSHnWhwRINuwCdkXG08okPqgm9QCBw2aNbSC/eshRgfJoSTkdWyAgPyIhxIaV/ElqjESApZMgFIB47Ho2IE0sRoVbkIDehSUT9HuPZaMHngFj@KpXk2rGIBfiOQ9Z3RMMYyNNYv2RIQwpdWjj4ILQ8Ik9CJwYWIEuPyTm1QvIypFSBUUAUNLKtEeCxNiQMFuAIMRKiMZHV69LJ2akEouMtNGsUC5mw9PKvvxEsojVI9rIGv4Yo1oST756SWbaNZcACOgPxjkLZUkjjM4n0dpvCb2p29UE4F6BXAbjiEj0YxbqljgBBNQYEdQuLWFKvi9rIXRmY1G/JYkWhOFQPpEGe@eR1gVFmj8OQAh5LplpXQLQb@APgJxAbjn3kh0/2DBCBHfi9qEDoNXAt8LmMggnj8MuhA0KLUCRWFxhk2ch7PhkYQ2E6gO4lHE3HjQJ3zOCgZRSjAgJXoCn2@KxPXpO@5bjYBOqxK451SKOxG2Obsd9DyXuOT3saSdGwgx4CecE1DGdBp@wDzB9vZdYxpAAYBBEwUrHqz7/5fW8wgH6ObTsIe4m6via9wB57gLDFkLVAFVFhA99yGVoAV8DReXMY4NpynZ4V4/D@TTIEQ4KNOgnGbo8EMGA4cWBqDa1rmI79PrVjypU8GMeAY4F41hW3FQ7XXCDcs7ogWDYAG5uRrZKjJyAlm3KVUb1x3K8QdXRCpEh/Jx9W5cOdNgXcFE3JZXV9UAN903LsE7xJ9ynO6@OlPFF7XjoBziN3NByD1YAaPxqBPQmRmbYF5ERoVmKwfwXSZYxmtghUnU3SCZVCSrows1PCmI5wHcD2Ks7cpIelTFO4dRWjvRUNA@0EJYujDTPhBhMYmOGGRhR02sfBrYEFQ8UJQcecID4i@7JO2pUPmo69dSmpqF0HpIN6AMYmEcYKjQBeKnIY6I1Lb2VSeNYN9GJzI72UJHH6IGQP9Da8ITbFyQCzgnJLh4OMmWJEDuhR0CeGWiyXHxB@HOrH6luwHh/1e2WMxN8S8zHp0wlxLX8wtgagyIEPTSzbpqM4mUFASRTDHLltCNlHNbHqWjQUske3x2bWLbH3K2Og9eHSS2y0hWoPjPKA1aoLs5xY4YDNRNJzQpgv7s3t0QHg@tbg4nsEWUPgvXgHCqlrAiWjU2qPY5huoMiToWMPQXcRO59PWG4dbw8Pn1ZHB5Oj9hdDIzJm83FR0PTFJ0Tjzi5UlOhmP2D1savm2gcm/NUP9/dsRd6WjoMFimChVr5quqWB7iVMA39@gbEEmL/UebOZtQgwFvwEBn@Djimk349BYKDPzsBHEMtfOP4Vy@hEvgSuwokc4Dq6cNT1l8/O0B@8oTyKAb5zX7ZqzAOIaaB54qKxIhWCQO1hQFSfSAkOssg86gdAS49CmxXUlTBCVDTgk4z8YlVpRx94jHbboZLmJhwbUiqQlih2CuDD3AhUyB@7LryMfTbFZKrMQNdsGkUaTBjgrYbxCGAn5qkyXweMh2EwIXSu1KRtw/1EgTwZd53p/0OJ2IgXvwNVK2Jgn75EDhuAqSBEMWHdBgTj3ZPAQztP3jCKEd@vQ/ANffAHwugmHoKlU20iWo1gRAGlNUsiAZ4QpMtKjYV0kqR9CBxfnkk7OztSVWpKBSgdQqmOpUMs5aF0yEoqKyGchiXWosBKWNtiLfBbR5q30p6nSgdFO8W49aMzkq1WtVrqFKyWmTyL@FTAmYDvAGgVH9CPpDQaWFQUsTkBQrVuX@DkvwThfAshH/nWQU/chwBxmToIi8HagsiZUVq3peKypsij1WvdA/Zpo5vtUYS42hVrAAHcVYA6uixdGppZXusC8p7Nln0nGrLbGugGWps1rHXkdfvstgWgmoQBEFNgloR8YaYMI5EgAM2fMDAv8AOOCvDL8S39BXto4D224bNupNeQ6VKY8wOqdx0fyw@AqQcVBtnvdp27QIEviHr63AIWjrvb2Abh2XDDj5M1xsfjMHZpL3n@6Vc9EMCmeIbWTQQB/dWicAl8Q1Gp/TullTTFF3bbLtkPYxfSvQf6sC0M4i13UdjeV5W8oKD@IFmfZXmAqQu0YYQDpm5Tv2FquOMeTZ/bO2U8XA8HeGvf8Zjk4ImxDbM8dzS/Fczw9pj0hG5g9XSeiDp0KUrOdDq1BoF/o694NS3sfgGOabxBlplnPBzHY37HZPMhoTkj/N03GRNIo2x1TaoHkdV17uAgIrF3l9LyuYBmWu271hUvXmJxO6mcmNAZQGabPu8Cg2gPAvKRZVN9wh532g9/HI2YMFnpnv5Cl9/vAnF8GzyrvyzcBQhkuuz2U1SOKYIN8wBRxcUedYVFzi2mulb3Bl3Z8KfrDw44yOeJCrajYefzRomowTIXWy4rjUZ3t7ftpP3BwfbWfAWKdWAHkDbTh/wROBXHs1y12Fsp3mlfU9e/LG0zP9a1BUGBa0WgIHHCZnoNYmG3@5QW/YQ9dq1wWbpHZZfopCn3XVnbss3IsQPXSTQzfdkygI9h3u2QaNkNriuy27IpviUm8ylEPeh4P99rNwM7xmTpDtX5AovE8xTMBFd0QQvuYpcdTPB354QdBteU37e7oI9bsfoCi6O6TBkg1t5s3rMf0lBcB2K37ZbwaitWse1u/V4lz4MghEQ1IkXNuFc8W9U4ctwgIhfsfh8vIEWPIn7frsCrbHMsX7WHfFotytubbUWKeTRyzO53CNdyB4G7VxnoFtzu1IBx2EfDnjy/1KgtjJJpPmiUFuFL4JvJ805rfgV/DykHLoCA@XYwjlkUtyvKnRYsifjvJhDCfFzw2k7cqVFZaFYY0XtVqkqOQ3s4sW7uhXrIc9zF5tRzVHGxngXC/7Nhdu8fpvdlVmqj2/37u10T75VLwUyz@4ZQSdEwf2IL0zC@3Gb13TEd06025Kz7gYLifHFQfC9SRkJGlXy8cu/t84vQRi@Ob/faHMt1YJ4/GMNUyTkE0efBAwnAwB@P1mS5mj2M/RcPzIknQdD76Zq6sDqVh0OhKrmg8QNYnHgBJKeBByGB/wWSTUJ1tq3I72uSZV@WPX9wnkA8Ed7b72KhB4JRCC5AWM5VpEL0sslXtjTxgu0/LRaEo0KycQbfnDDZJokWe5GZZ74dUrY8nC54kQwuWo89iLLiINQIg5NlK59XFIE3Qq898AEshWK7QbggzzeaIgLhU8xgnT5ptUh2Nq0aVXNOGkSsiqTT4b2ypeGT6Yht47zgTVtZq9PISqoqZaW2XyWGxECpC0Z0K6i1Btd32IPjuSSd@JbH9gCwnFJa4xsNENvg7tLQ8nuQV77yHbaWZwchXy7nezIvMWn/4x96yabbgAKRnhPBjBn4uFEceHQYTA75uMnox6ORhZt22AekMi5f7VOfHJNo4sT2kO@1Qej16vRlJdkoSbav4eUcE8oVLLhQoaoPOFgxFxrHphdQrkHJwItWKVEQz449n0ycXjyMNAhUfJuyjZh0cwAwCRHMj8MANbBAnpEexbyKLVZ@GINs3SC4YmukiMkf/8C3h6DSQRXCcjo8269cGZGAfTHZnoxtB2PAOu3kIw2DBERGJkNUPkYtB/2n/LtC7KHF9q1AE9V01waH4Ts3T44viHpCJNxvx02cmtOXs8cvfv66ZXQan4mn0z/9Ssd1Y8Y38St134zEAklBanPUq9VqA6qXtRIRs1MxIQt3dtlG5kKp@GwiMpaZuNJdGI9tCjO9oxO2C8O22nxMOnC31Y9gfsCrwrrmk6aRlceu4zkxUS9iUsZDCWCdLCjxbWSC2/y4o4BNslPyiQxRV1SbmGUD3jhDXNzE8hpfp0tepdWlSf0p7Y5ZGn9d1IqlBiMne9moN1kppL0Atzlb79qTjh6lXGm3p18ZxSmwLQgB/LGOM@fku6ezrNY0Pn2KIG4RxblUY0vHOL2zs/Nn5ycXL49fvroANs45lZnTIPSspYlAJRi5EFAOA5ftGwM/QodGD5uNR8xuCI8SQFkmWYvUwY0TsFCPFoYlYauoille5HXMkizqblUm5qPvkMTUkXMm7USwUrRq5gqpAiDzYE6Owa6myIPizLaYK0aOSBpAkAoEMfAFwou3bYSt1zJ4zvBDfAemJ2SsQjFSl1DbgZBWDpzgzWE4kluJmP8vYT4CP/Iw5gj1EOYALDw0@srAp8fPvn314mRz7JVhE5gNkIWGrBzVOZlCIgB2sM80HLeDU70Jku381DCA3R/yPSbLXZq2aLFdhJrUR8PswtzGScEW0yKc3ATtiEaO3QgMaa8HlqF7E6NhAYvKd4gW20RiBhigLfxcgYgCwkaNzW1dMBwTCJns97xxlsGxnqNtJyPaVP/zb37PT0O0Yyj/XVLuQ/nXvPxORwZtbp9zHBesQba8fnZOIvBWnHDPmq7QhA4DHZLjQ7jteMDBa8YQBOfILuld9iO3XgM/QQjATLR8aOzYeDTsyMM4HlV1Hf075L19ja2v0ynIAWylBpmi/v0YD6eAfdb3ynu7pg5Iqtdph2zPc4BrvrxDRamCCgnXzqjxvmuTer1OxAjCNNrYq3FG6lnrXUl8v0A0C7ACDwVaBNpAk2ULqGsmzeSslTcVbIqzUDIl0qmBl@dyAUchswKAKPjZT/ghgicKElbh9imdxsyo3qQhDsQXfkA85BM7opR2pEJHvG9FFDZ0d7m2i3taK9qsrYpBfINgFwhWFbepDgEN@bctmuND@e95udU21M@dbcdrFrpzvHmKRr59BgZpIUcXfoBr/aeAK5GLerGkm3vKyjwRk64AW5wVn6BLmAcwr2zqfAhG0fGTk2ffnJ1fbJwCYZDSbTCJSM16vq1qhVZnUZBu6XzK0q9P9YvnX5@mjFzFKqm6jdW2zm8jdsdgb/gq@uZQrGJjINP40o7Zlq96yrLKLYQsavUVwCd8yW9jVFmZzVuderPtZzaG/7TtiFZGy@GpLCi1I3ZASyJbDMyzdG/gZXAF6nHP2RM1Rgjn4@oplHRnAY94FJt6j17reCZB0JZ7DmJWrq9hq/BzMpwH6fBgJ5IvWcjqm2Q5li1srN@uIsIT2mCByVrLBbOR5jOe2bFjZpYPQX3o2Bw6YsaV53/sTBRkAM/iZdIAiQiuWrDc6IblATDNF@uhPYctlVvhTULBouaCeo76MsUHJ/1y4x@MUBDGkH5EQ9fp1qxGa0oW2@L3nQnQopHrxDJuxk81zK@AGllBAsy6S3Evv37QSQ4OkHR/P8@OCJyPgV/nwYgsc9qnNC29gLSGPB1D56ABlHwz9gCuzx4vKFp4Sr4LVGgMfJRSJFowipzQoHm9MoyuDem05wzAS8hKAQzKV6a5PFxgKXnIRSWwoZxVP8eF3lXG/KQDESscs1qW5vg9OpWliaRUO8gd@C5N3lxLirihA@xURnJEo3f7eEY69604mYSLow2rEycNWGDwZHMUnAgemsXjMJAoOKDTR7@kvg8qIwPaHigIscZAZ6gU0hPchcU5uxW78Itkr/W2lziRZm4AvjCr11hKUpuDQ3jfJu243W/76BVqN/rPdE2vzeSs27jRwZErTTk7bJj5Ui6fz/o5OeujK3v8GDOZeRY85aUmauIUgNSsq9SAn@BZG1m/lrXqcrbXKOZYC3jN55UZNPgc6dosa8317GNwTAX4EnLtkLORguIwNM2cA34ooaxe8KzRTBaJOMXjijh81snnEQcte4kIfNbbF3lmptoXOsudakmApA@8VI3XlOHHHzPmHsTqh3slOTgslnZyGZI5EvVc@@nbt0@ua1LL6he17zvnV@fnf6O0ZSnz5Ew0d8UayelCRs8Zn/Z1/f379xA6kFZTa2odpaVKnZbc3N/P1Qp7lVzhqGBKhVqGuKZhmopcLCoX7V2/5jjOKOr14BcM8TwTOM8qiuYRXLJ5LknlknTxDs/hHO7AP/YH1@IV7zvsS/KZgWxeOwqRv58KmeYj0KXS3s7RI0CV5tlVrR4RIfNZyNwImff190IGIqRMs9mZz/P1Vr2uNZvTptpptoTMTMhM50KmKCJrckKmMa2/YF20njZ5X/nvgc3fwrOudlqj829Pji9OCsW6mimeHj8pFC9efZ0x4a28fMXKEr6@ODl@evbqZaHIW/382euTV@fwPeo0j47ymqqqR1qzA1hMv8o38404jsnbyxzMjafN6StdrcOg3wqZFwxSbQMabQXgPwmZVqYlHxZ3z/bOjg6LhmtcG@aVefU8OFv8kednZ1DhTI0PQWgMjaHZM01zatBXxo1xMzW84MzsQZHCP8ODomP0p8bA8A3fNFc7uufPOwuenwXQVQDN4qkRY69GH56Ds7Pn0FkfBv4A/xzDQASnxjX8Ga7JrneXkFcZ7bbQAjXtlPdGxb3vW8zulA86LTp14o5IClK7JXVqGT1qt3Wu6GIRtBSr5/PLy6fHL48vL3VMn6b1bP4orx7B1Wjm68njMNNrIv@0@k5bkOTJmzdv8Pdmcj3hJVZ4MyFvkgvedHG/IgbBUQL6Zvl8M4Hr@o5O1gtk7ZLlVrkzmyuK8qgt1SROiSxTcKSyaLanxT4pisw/HYB1MEuQA8h7ZaXZ3CvD@15FUWUDa3eVd2a9nlQVlSAUpakYhBKZzfk/eTavy@xS8J@i4Mfk3lRkqFbK8DadydO6XJfxG3zCVrN5E4sMbgallqx0lPmcf4O7rNR5n00FCMQM4P/oL4ggXSVSZp5Bj@CT3bIC@QVVdvfkSv4g@dfYAWJksSSVgEZRsqRW6yhXyu3vtg47uU5Orue0XLvZma5eipQhoG@p1jTMDHJPyGi1F6JZFCXUohquqgUu1VyI90sHNUnO3b4q5kE@lz9q5Q4O@GC53KcdBVpD3yJcGVA0IpN6s76Q/lIRlCb8ZiThL5TnM1AIXgcuRU5Wy9rtqWEw@Fq3kZ1lrHmNdU/mYgqd6BXrXpZqbBlVnIlZK2yZHXEuZmfdOfrdnKkwj1nerdVyu7y8X6mBoTdzSY0BNUkRKmhk2WyCgW1HRZKAwwoQ1ejSgeMLmdGaZufL5bJehPv0q72T4lSo4XIjX9sUVZErOqkcsA4zUSRAbNEFKU/IvgGxo@taIQn6/R3@HYIkyC4pBAnUdTFNxxxhEoRubwJx646QiShc3rlFx5ROxuMJXVxPnKhqffgAsS@7/vLDP/8t/P4Av9/y52//66CM97/88I//@ed//XcBnv/wlx/@6T/@8sOvfwe/f0l@v7v9EwSkaIeU99OCKTzH3PfA5DsBDn6GUkiFXwBd3tge4laME6MnhRDLEDTkQbF4UClXDkrFSqFyUNktm3vlcsEsFsz9yv6BUQAnWjH3KuUDs1DZPSjt7u4eQG35YF/IUL/n9HUdvJMpioQVIJDHA3B1PCoYaMMmeLse7Ts@fUSmck95lOmlH8i4QsRSpW1A7oCHQ0FbFDJDOyuTCCJuQFw2CmOwMOXDcUXc2xerOXiKh2IJikzEU5kYEmijKLVFUWkddA7F/bJYBReuSo/NQyLuH4hVcX9fVGoiHZRFcY8U90XxrYObxESszQHllBULYgjYZE0j8FNVAetHDY6OTES5La5omJL8py1JlqT9oiQpUg062bkFgrQBaZwy8aAowseQxuPQJ0Ztzkf/q5Xhw6tqFFshJo@sd8it9g5E/AwgdT5jm@Vurlow1cKRwPV4zxQyc6GHh3p2D2oYPYBdrTeFrITDSyUho5aC3SCTzWYh5njZFEvimVbXk0CiqbMooo2BBbp0LY1LmkJIceG6h/9DjbuGShnRH5BIaMB3oYZ2RcwkhuwGHVSbd1n/nGEHNsj5bLGgmZxgrz5HnljVC3ZasdUhyufvHHdWKalNFqFDpjAnwJr56OLg3f67yrvnr85enZ0eVSvVChibTPRJCcrmZ/@bWqY6kkq7UgkikEaGI2juK5lmcV@LrJtMJ9kik3f3FQJvzJQUzUwf3eXCW25605XSlvfJtcdCMECk8rPeYOAUf/b8/SfI0SWJEDO791mt87863J6ccQnJ4l5ZVHBrMXp3@e4yI2TKRCyWQVnyOoS2uv43RZiIBwd7lb2M8KOu35fkQ@0iR@lTCN/H3rYk5Th0nlu4quovEhUoPB9DNruYqARnKqZ/w@b6NzZ71z6x/@II3wTEi2k1FqxwYBfYUi/J4eHUVgdmcbpNIGMtrlQri4XtherzDQjswqktijAKTjbSQACmMhBlyE7DrBGnjp3BE1KZZAS80hb5BhYxhWZYOB2lJqyu2DNMmtB6BZeV9vk8B59ztDg9ttfjZPO6xSug5@HOpi0nrZVbAC2jAzBS25ASMr@EDMhV5UUPBfKTybjVHrI2JaWJobCsTL4vRTEXcnHBqwlIdm5UE34p28oMs8naZ@/xY/vdqOV1aorXiPGZz3tgt65kh4Pk4obXUM3aCJCtxa183uk0POWX8ogh7zXQyMHY2HOkzBaS9huJuCKl8LHlq5/9TuG05efNTmFcyL1tfCxYDaMwhR@wreAWvgfmpayU48bHvF@z6vDDxHaNE2Cu81ZtfSMFmlzJbuNjy@o0DKXmQsN8/hSIATyjlpvPdxQY3IXKzYY19/FjK@82pzVXVRWEelc6PG3FUOjkG/hela369PBjawztqzI8GzCMqwDy0G5dBtAf4FcDHnPxLVHnOE4RvSmg5zUaubeHube5xs7Ox9ZU9ToFzv6qsRQ8Ij9F5Fd1RM69XVUsxhIWu8niV071Ky0XEbEA2gdMLoxWWnIMc2@hZrScDfP/Bg) Languages not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-d 3 -v 98` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- zkl, 85 [local](http://www.zenkinetic.com/zklDownloads.html)
- PingPong, 88 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/pingpong/www/pingpong.zip)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Cood, 91 [online](https://jesobreira.github.io/cood/)
- Set, 93 [online](https://avellar.ml/set-lang)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)

Cubically is a painful esolang I wrote. Go check out the [repo](//git.io/Cubically) to see why I call it 'painful'.

## Cubically

The Cubically code started as `+52/1+55%6E0`.

- `+52/1` set the notepad to 7. `+55` got it to 97.
- `%6` prints the notepad value as integer.
- `E0` exits the program.

Cubically was really useful for this polyglot because it only calls a command when a number is provided immediately after a valid non-number command character. There luckily weren't any commands next to numbers, so I didn't have to deal with that.

## Incident

NOTHING BORKED INCIDENT :D

## Cubix/Prelude/Moo

Trying to put the Cubically snippet near the top of the code displaced Cubix' `4O6O@`, which was necessary. I moved the `4060@` up a bit higher and it fixed Cubix.

However, fixing Cubix displaced some parenthesis, which made Prelude angry. I tried for a while to coerce it into working, but it was taking a few hours so I abandoned my approach. (Somewhere along the way, Moo stopped working.)

## Cardinal

The `%` to print an integer messed with Cardinal, spawning instruction pointers in the four cardinal directions around the `%`. So I spaced the Cubically code to put the `%` over an `x` and rewrote it to look like this:

```
+52/1+55x%6E0x
```

## Whirl

Whirl is a really nasty language which only cares about 1s and 0s. The Cubically code contained one of each. I rewrote the beginning like this:

```
+555/2
```

which still sets the notepad to 7. Then I changed `E0` to `E2`, because `E` doesn't care what number it's given, it exits anyway. Thus the Cubically code turned into this:

```
+555/2+55x%6E2x
```

## Notes for future answers

Make sure to put a non-command character between a command character and a number. These are Cubically's command characters: `RLUDFBE@%+-*/=:`

Comment: Since Cubically's TIO is broken is there a place we can test it?

Comment: @WheatWizard it's fixed now, URL updated.

Comment: If Moo breaks, it means you mooved (lol) (or broke) a moo (or an oom, since there are a couple of those) (and I guess adding a moo would do it too, but that seems unlikely to do on accident). I'd wager it just got caught up in an accidental cut/delete.

Answer (score 7):

## 106. [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/), 3286 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\4n;iiipsddpsdoh coding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@ 
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d1114O6O@x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[  "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWw WWWWWWWWwWW/"78"oo@WWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw              (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zinge  ";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ ppppppp            (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002758 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3378 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc9tIkuCzEfcP5qUEsg2ABECCFCV@S2pbnnF3u6Wz7HavSVoGQVCEBQJsAJQoy3TMvexOz23c7c3OTcz27k3vTNxFTMTd015cxG7sRGzE7ev@iv4D1/@gL7MKX/yS5Nk7WgQKVVmZWZlZWVkfhPu6P/rhhwx@yLFrX53ZbkAC0w/IwLMuTE8lH1@Rfd3yK6Uyx1Eozx1MDcs5I8HIJJYzmQZkaNmmzxl6QNpkEmJRMUEyxDP1AQPjhq5HsAoZn9vEIsZkQvq2PlINYlsA@6hYJebYfWORt1CeIb47RujA9CaeCVefOKY5IP7ENKyhZVCqxJwFpuNbruOrxDLOyaVl22Rg2lAhYcWQARmZ@qksRljlBi5H4GNMlhiPn7ImwDhm1Hhzonu08S6ZUElEMrj09MkEmOQy5AQYD6yx6RMrEHxi6r6FEoUqvukMqNwmsaxdojvpVpILSyc68Dv1KG7f9AJonkrxkpHpmYBSR@Jnnj4m4qVnBSACFOsBOTZ1jzzzTFMCKqAO0zf0CfCxQBKIuUghwIaoVG3NpnB49EgA9bEaqj4JuIxXfvZvP@F0orZI9rQB3xbPN7jDzx@S62wX08AFIAMVTzxRl0jrPfEL3a4J35nWL5x5cw6wciAVmxTcSVDQlQkwqATAYEHHJKaUi5I6sVOESXNJFymjYlAD0AZ57JAvZNoyY@p5JvCRCFU/h0bbrnMG8oTGelMH5eGQnSKowHCdgS8T8wKk5jpMR@4llfCzkQVK81Eleh8EpBsoe9YhqEChS4DthRKN6PquPaVwUNMP0ABBKlAVMT4eki/IULdsrALliIpx7Zn@1A6wztQZoObHlmMOVBKxYbgDBBq7F0BOB6Q0A/rQONXzKFMADIpwaVOx6Lu/@OvB2RngOTAM1xuE5voFGbjGdAwM65RZHUwRDdZ1dJuyBXAyUmfVgcCFblsDPUDyzlVIgjJBqV66U3tAXCDoXVrQtUb6BXTH4dA0ApMZuTsNgEeZjPVz5i8sZrnQ8LHeB8VSApQ2bbZC9h@AlgyTmYwyngbDKlEmh0TwC6/Evbq4t9U1gTdJlXLZQuGsAfam5mgWPAk3Gc4XB4k@0XqeWS72I3symoLXgBLHn4A/8VCYhg7N8dGtBOADZdKngqa@CEyddtJLU/BM0oeeHTWM2gizAayvYM8NMSQ6jeAWTcwcpCwMrBOMLPBX3ITtXgJhyhs6UrBpB4nrZzqQCsIGHbAGMYo0Z7Fp5w5YOmLrm6Sq9C3QDtoBOJtQGak2Ani5xGAAG9NeqlOM9SvAYjAnnWiSWENQ8hjs1rsihomdAXqFyTwdEplSw/AtsCN3SIpKqVK5RfmBVzhQXoL3eFu4UcfY@CU1H5CheUls3Tmb6mdgyK4DVXTDMCdB2IOgJX4AfWTZEdJMJfTqqj/isvvLtKl3C/19igZ6H6a90EfraPYgqDGIWrGhlxPdO6M9kQwsD/qLfbVMHQAulojzrxFkgYHX/AYWoqEJjMycmcY0gO4Ghnw5sowR2C5y57AOy7zjMnnISlMHl6MMY9LIjNa@X@LUQpyFbGxEoaBGV/GA10dU7YUMqvx0xs2YdX@8BrEbswgeKpWrFnQVbC8UGoznJxhLgPuLBm/as@IAI5YnCBi6OnRTMJZREEz8OrgbKxhN@yqotfDMu3ocHDmo2ULgXVmBy9J92@0XxroPnakQUSgY0741W2oRzYsF/sbnLmAYH/qkBf7/qymYiCgMfUFq0PwHCJwq4unQSlGwKw@AFEgFSYlDX8UQ7BF4gJMrxxB5ldq9Cj2ElwmPvYyXIIG1Yrk8cMfoMsgLOrxgvPCxB25mCK6Fm1wFI5CDYhBeb7kT0xGFBaMUJEpQlBo0OhAE9Y1rOeK1sLW1JdSFtiBDag9STUztYSoPqT2aUmgK4VRM0RoyTWFph9bAvJ4w70SYZ1IP1TbDEOitNRH1Tr1e7sl6RwvvJbxL4JfADQG0gjfAI0itFiYliW9fQkPV/pC1/imT7IBaw1PTOePM2cT1AvL50cPD0@ODZz9p8YWp7xVsq19wYEA8HUN3gxCYX1MfYtmoOiSfum7QogrDfAr9OB3hDj13HHsHnzONkUv4bJnHyAxDYwUdyhjjtslVVLqNpVPH1sf9gY75FO0zcECfQQREPrNwYBou0OFigXU5nim0vOha@KSkxIK3CzBlcJOTq/WDKp9GRSsAm@cu9qEkdVpUtcoCCpgKrNYcWv6IXhZAV9haLaG1/XF/SC9rAOrhqAhDLE4aUC6fYMiJA7PrwgTjkoKNXcdlrIC8LEcvPKU3FZzpOn4WfdYCM31zOIUwtNC3HEzfAqbUqhRy2O9bm0BBLsh6dF8D5k3768QGLmy0MqyRBcEHUy@wzUF4/5efDkABq@oZ6Vc@xLfnceIU5IaqUoYbtRVWxQd6Wa/ZN1MbZj@34DB0jGl1O06sx4UdkyjKSPdAm1eRNsEa8QJO9jZ7h65iTwdmdF9PhMp0cbRktR1rTDUJdxz6qTfdUH1prGf1cU7g2a4@oFjYXM0yE/UyRZgz/QwaV0jNH1Wvfwc@oyGZJJMzGM6CKbvifOw2RVoT/N7UQUPIYkXva2bB9fW@tUGKyMTOJkNm/QOHH2Vo6@cseYrJ9U1ljfGsM5j8RfdNYBAQQcw60Q2zcElvG32KM/UnTBWYugGfZ7PrJhDLMSD0dZLEJkBopk0vH2J21BAM6BvIKq6HKCkRWUtCtfX@FQ7Row@3HyR4ls8TBfxJy8jni2WiuMl0JVl5mUw21zeMsH6ttr42W6ShCAwXZpbmbX0WBhprrNtKaZBKbvS5UUiTpNa5JP1Ch2DH1n0wkCAUs3kBaqGXm4wWxw5jautekrrBZBN2olnppolNUmdiGa5thZYZPWzyhctRZoIGl9/oJamKT6vyHUBgh@OyEqfWd2jXCHByscGO7uCeWFyPM6eUYajuJtkZ7iV@N/bekXthsuv6MertWq7u4H4Um1oGTBZWqw@M28wV103oZb0Uz9dyFRj22vw6eeK6HkzsfFJSixjROHSxD0Zo22Zzl2ePjzbbtG/Zrk9O6PUmWUAE6vvsut6a02KzdEcxRqyPxen11dYyRYc3ckCvG5Sr22euvVM9K@hw2WgBU2@IXj6839XDxR5K0271UHF84zpaeN/o2s/h7zbjwAUD8OUWBjpxcr2hbHRn4bRmcwNhHoALROsb96hYjS3L880bTYqpwjNGl/pVdP8jxpFNco7GkckVjZMhrsMKtSokAo/Fzn8Mte2bqQ3u5q1W0O7e1oiUms9tE3w3va4ol5SK2gfW0IrFu/uuoT01p@ZaX3LUf2OCAd2k8rszVQybkQ1nwAUQHu7xxFBvw1ngnbjGkR2fbnQ9um1Bd781rlnrdCYQa09w6nwMiWNMrFY8c6aTBeWmZPd06jy9WXKjSdTH3cECk1jyob6penv0tBCQ@yb9rncldXI4dmGu644hmnDuoP8QKV2dYNcFxDQnwfzGegChiHe7K8FgBeJYiEtAp9a5r0Dgs3EEWHQ7pU1TdApcq8GczDGDK7xukvU6h9p3XftDdAN@dWBhuAZBKG513qajOjm5GvchgjOSxbY7yD@aLoK0cGq8Ua3HgDK4I87y6mLTDaNVaulpFSpcEaMbcPGKuC@HO4eQZ3nhPpEfb8ZmHjuGZ9L18WgJlmRw1X46hhg6cD2VUDhR1PN5SeJYJQzDzhwAi6DodhjuSLCdNp9AcBxQWGtIOh2SvZ7Vi3VtTlqEr/Ok12NY6dr44WxC97GesqqdrN5rZQVFEbJC16mTokBBTRtGxbWg@gLc0KI3xmfSdOLoY7oJgumopQ220wLBKm6vjXRnYJvkOaiXhvCux/YL2KbUM1ym@effD8JdxzMTGjm2fPB9Zw7ulLtjc@Re7jG6IfWDyUTHXUvEARNVm21VKA8OiH9pBcaIbTZCLP380bNquFMU7uHDwzH2oxQXTKloWcCDHjClMW4GrskMLSQc14oaBbOV6dghl9YgGPkqRJ6OYdKdqHj9E1II5gSei4Yqk8dkYOKseYCMvZmCbm3XPafrrMjJP/@e7Y9BoYUmhOmIPN2wTVEkMFJodFPKMNwpcB0heWt6bggiopBhzjVFRwTdxGT5EjFGOt24A0tUom0rJMO2rh4cnBDlkAh44ADX1xvWUMwePP3xF51ir/WejAvmv/y0IF2HcuM/UnY1n5dJBNKYo12li4tQnJQKhM/O@LBZuLVNd3Jjo2K9iYiYpuqKtqHGdFec2p15Sbeh6F6jgz4Kt5sdH/oHPEoUNes0raw4ta2xFRDlJCAVPJVhgkggxfbRCZ5zwC0VrJKdkXdkhLaiGESrFOGJCcTGXbxx6@NokbOcXowuPDT7U7pIc1FSS@UWbU72tNVs05RnDlzc5@286l72Cn4klW539lGxNAOxuR6A3y9gzzn8/OF1Vm0X373zIfrk@bnQYGvk0L2z18ePjw9Pnh08e34CYpyzVmYeud5YT1wEGsHEhhnCyLXpxjnIw7NM/3a3cY/6De5eCCiKJKuTJsRjBDzUvdixhGLlFT7LkqyMepK4bKkwdB9Di4SujhxTbYeKFfy0m5MjA0DhQZ@cgl@NmAfDuV7jrmhzeNKCBinQIAoeMxw/rWvYYimFZwLfw2cQetiMNBRtagK1HgjbyoBDvhkMY3JtI@b/jzifwDhyO@cIdRvnAMzdRj1F@NHB48@ePz1cpZ0iG8KsgMQWkjqrdDiDCAT84JBaOO6HR3bjhucZIscAfn/Edj11O3FtPrmwfKtvm9SShuiYbejb2CnoUqmPnZugH1HJge2DIx0MwDP0rwJ0LOBRVbpBxXapFIfwGRCAGo9zMuE5hPVbq/va4DguIYIyXrPKWQpHMfvrjoZ0zcJ3f/HX7DhIN4D012F6COk/Z@lXBRTQ6vkBxmMsGhTLF4@PiQ@jFWv4WJ@l2oQDBg5IlgPzJmsMErygAkFwxmzS3gSP2PkC5AlKAGGi50NnR@mZXk/EDeV6oYDj@5lrD1W6o2LOQA/gK@n@8ldTPJ0D/rmwU9nZ1grApHIRIVQshlCZMISSVAcT4i6sSet13yDNZpPwPkTSZmunwQRZyOqvyvzrmNEswHIsFOgQqANVkhpQ1g6riVk9r0lYFXuhoAmk14BRnukFBgqRJgBEwmwnlAcPI5EbigqU7pizgDrVqyjEgfjCcckY5UTPaEWIFEDEcEs8t2K7yco97mKmrFlNq4F/gWAnCFbn15lO5xXpBl2nFx4mImAwf7vGkBxI/3zNCaPYeg5WDxKJy8eAsDVk/8RxcS/nEXBLxFKhVC5oO1Kqp/AhKuAX@8U7QAk9AXqWYVpv3Il/8ODw8SdHxycrB2EopLAMJhCh3cx3FVXu9OKEsGT1kVA/flQ4efLxo0iUaa6SyRBCJDOiZTbXUVvmdAP1F2zbZJU2LVghpBXviphOp5RHdMlgFXtSWkgBPmDLuitURel63uk1210ns0L@3bpjaxk1h8YFqa5PD60JZI3PeRxtBj1zz8Fe1Ghvv8QnZzINjs4r3fA5yd58PCZAbNbb9CmeaNsJj8iU2oWBeVFwprbNqcmGFJ8Vmwstk3iQgFpgBOkpEcZexDV4nIhhDRlOyBrcytJ@micStigmna4Z6whFdcTmiPTEnu7A9MCDeTKF9qmbZjNJerwM5hKPg2T6AVManPTSWdYVnVGAw4iXygcW3VLRveg4RVxyYo4t5VnED7qP5OALuDM80DGCttlWv6G3OjMSH6m46UyM6k9sKxDxMMpMxZkatEaUsAFa0zbxLEuz1gsPzpDofEueHpE5noK8jt0JSWbHD80o9RQmSOThFJCDMZjkk@kY4Ib09tTEscIkn7sKVAY5ChETHaAihm1Qx4MKUFdH5mxgncF4I0oyOKaPNC05XKNLeZjVCuCNmah@jHsAacF80IGglMT0jq5azsCcicKlINV7KB3IFy5fXAgSv2ID9FRSeERpsHw8KXIZehD23eRoz5JbqNVid7DYg2o1deRzeNoFYnygeBJ4n0ESRlJxONYnRJzS810@UQl9FLuiI/uBJxGljaPaJXFIPk9nB3CjBSqhNYc0Zdl4vFLEQ7VioQV6xlzfGeDtrTUhHU1Ve5CmRCSSxYn9Awg6cEoscRBKQpU6RQvDMPyrI0eXMA9Cjtg9S8lyOCv3AGptMe3IZyPaAUEWtNWkfZ8kPiHpgUyqtVo91MaiU6wRMIvV8UgtANo1zi6KO0G@4QkGkBq6MoB6APM9CxzK/qem40B/FcFmxtA7iT4FI/MkOfo1ghyfF81QChnG4k/CIxHAaGbBHR8K17YLUU220KCTy8YcRv/XXRz@h2EAcFX4UUEtNK7FrN26KkBIJrXF7Kil5cu5fD7r5MSsg0HJ/fs4J51nIeY5VXmVnwGQkrWlBtgzxEitrNPI6k0xO2iVcrQGPObz0jVUeO8X1OusPi9k70NMIUOOx3qnmPUl7A5FVdXmwB/2kGxBBpu5FnnCz/DkLZLPWvk88qBmT5GB94XuSZ6OLt2TAp0FN8JQt3A2jtzIglp@@CGj7cCsa2@nLLp7pfJWLkMy@3wh13348uWDi4bQ0Ycl9ave8fnx8ZdSVxQyD454bZtvkFyByxRyxXe7hcLr168hCCSdttpWe1JHEXodsb27m2vIO9WcvC9rgtzIEFsrapoklkrSSXfbaViWNfEHA/i6IzxGDkFQHVVzDz6idiwIlbJw8grPAe5twT/6B5/4Ea9bNCfMpiCrny2JiF/NuEz7HphTeWdr/x6waubpp17fJ1zmPZe54jKvm6@5DMS6mXa7N5/nlY6ah26XV/LNTrOpttuzttJrd7jMNZeZzblMiUch5bhMa9Z8SpF1HrYZ1vxXIPDP4N5Uep3J8WeHByeHcqmpZEqPDh7IpZPnH2c0eKokj1hYxsenhwcPj54/k0us1o8ff3H4/Bjy/V57fz@vKoqyr7Z7wMXso3w73wqCgLw8zUFHediePS8oTSD6GZd5SiGVLrDRlQD@HZfpZDriXmmvVLSLF0XtXDt/4h7Ff@TJ0REUWLPiG9crjoojbaBp2vbRztH@rGg@L14Vr2bFsXukDSBpwr/iGJJWcTgrnhWdoqNpaWw3/I2P3CdHLqByoVowKwaItTiE@9nR0RNANgTqb@CfVSwil7PiBfwVbY1@Xp3CXLnY7XIdMNjXJlidqglqUVB3BMHqVXYmX13PSztfdeigUKn1OubMCno8kYVup1arCb1GpuB3uwXWEfgSWDFCzOenpw8Pnh2cnhZwojxrZvP7eWUfPq12vhne9jKDNkpVbW51OUG8fPHiBX5fXF5cshRNvLgkL8IPPBX43Srvuvsh6Ivk/uISPhcbkCwmyMJHFDuV3vVckqR7XaEhsJaIogmBjshr3VlpSEo8jR9q4D20Mo5ROxWp3d6pwPNOVVLEIpZuS6@0ZjMsKkmuxwsz3vUEcj1n/8TreVOkHwn/SRJmhte2JEKxVIGn2bU4a4pNEfMgC2tdz9uYpHDXkOqIUk@az1keXEWpyXC2JWggzvX@P/25PvEnRMjMMzhoOGS7IsFM0pS2d8Rqvhb@a21BY0S@LJShjbygC53Ofq6c293u7PVyvZzYzKm5brs3S38kIUPACiOraWkZlB6XURtPea3EC2hFDVw/dW1TtWFeV641BDHHPiQXf6paLZ/L73dytRqjlsu925KgOiDn4ZMBSyMiababsfoTS5Da8L0moYAhPb8Gi2BlMOaI4cJotzsrFil8o9/KXmf0eYOiJ3M@gg4Ni6IXhQZdMeev@azudbQeP@ez1/05js05TaJjamW70chts/RutQEjgZYLS4pQEiahwPR1g/YwcP5oSQKIWIJGtfrmmeXAeLxg2vlKpVIowXX20c5hacY1cGWZLWPzCs8snVRrFGGG@H6Ng/CvD4q@JLtFCO9tW/eIOxxusXyIY0nfNCGUMG0b12QwzINoxx5cwtRii8uAR4AgB4rhMz7WzalpXk6nl2b8eWD5df3NG5il0M/33/76T@H7e/j@gt1/8T9qFbx@/@1/@m/f/ea3kPmP8P0H@P7999/@1U/Zlz7/Ab7/lMr7Q/hNwbEvB7j@/fff/vJ333/759/A97@E32@Wv9/96u/Y3/8O/2Hyt9/96g94YQ@A69c//@6vfgYs/grTfwZp@Auzvw6TqVyW/DpKQr2/WQL@@fff/uXvwvTP0iCpfKj6NeT/JpX/NcehMrdIZTdKaNwTXOGpaWy/y8JsSHlmjfsJaHQ8NUa4MWkFGGZA/F/kVNR/qVSrVqq1cqkqV2vV7Yq2U6nIWknWdqu7taIMEUZV26lWappc3a6Vt7e3azLRSpXaLsSDzsAaFgowYms8T2gCppl4lLeJh6BdddTmMgNzCEH2PTITB9K9zCDKINMq4cvVbhEmtnQeIBKJXOM4IxIfpoPAuViUp@BeK3vTKr@zy9dzcOf3@DIkqXnPRFIUoCfyQpfnpU6tt8fvVvg6xDeKcF/bI/xuDSYIu7u81OArPL9DSrs8/9LCgyyEb8yB30gQcUsIDEeqSuCrKByWT1qMGZGviYSad63Ls87PepIgCsJuSRAkoQFItvh0/5Ma2DJoGGtXxBgPMgXGajCsNDwzmHqOWFPAcxKlJjXmjKV/k@LJO4epiO7hdICSrBN@p8ZjNoA0xRqSalf6ubqsKfI@x7r1jsZl5twADytu10ij1sAwC4aaZpvLCsiWUOYyStnddjPZbBbCtGdtvswfqc1CGHG1CzTc6mIEhrGPGoVybVLgPBP3bQb4C1U2XlYr2JYz4mfyf@RHBQotwMk10E/zmQkbGa5wxO8yhprvM/QcCTm@jvcCpg5dXag/QUnr9RN6jLvTI9L7zy37ulpW2nRWBFPjOQHZzk9qr3ZfVV89eX70/OjRfrFerVfBeWf8d5Jb0d47nzQy9YlQ3hbKEOi1Mqxx2q6UaZd2VV@/yvTC3WVxe1ci8ERdc0nLDDH@iMOP1fAklVrzfHkxppEuMFL90eDszCr96Mnrd9lCQRAI0bI775Um@2vC5cERU7HI71R4CXfl/Venr04z4IAJX6qACeYLJHSxC5HOLOfQf2bOp/9MM8nw4TF6wnJTysH87MsSuIdabae6k@F@KBRuWk6D0nhmOTRhxjUdr5taHnjWEx2n3U48vYTEk@lb04u9B0H3gSsm6D/SeaFLSWXRH1hDHod80d6GCd07M2S6z0JyePa/0wPfEu3RiViK20RSvKvEeiEpNtjuH6KwGnESqKATgEl@kWXiNFK0WlqDWE1EBneYfYYU8BPVyLcwiatOlAurJzW49HYZ5aQNtVO8pOrn8wx8zthi7THGA9ZsVhY/AntjPFZgiGFtaQmgU@zhaka3KITNvEszDD0QYwwy@eBmLNWHibYUtYmykBSG@Ykq5lwukMcNDpudmzS4T0VDusYFgMb78f37xqtJZ9xrSONWgPd8fgyu81y0GEguaI1bitaYALONoJPPW73WWPpUnFDmx60iAANtxOxL17GmnVaoLl@S33Yc5b3Tkx91nLzWk6dy7mXrray3ivIMviA22Za/AuFFohSD1tu809Cb8MW1iAVJwDCS1xuLu5hQ5Vy0W287eq9VlBo2VMznH0FjgE@/Y@fzPQmI21C4WrFh37@v5@32rGErioRQr8p7jzoBJHr5Fj7XRb0523vbmUL9ugj3FpCxJWAe6i3qAPABfw2QMVNfwjrjcYbszYC9cauVe7mXe5lrbW297cyUcU9m4q8XE8Uj8zNkPm0jYu5l2rCoSGg0LfIfWfWP1JxPeBmsD4QsT1I1GYe5l1AySXrDHF0R/bV3tM6Fq5/h9iX7gR/9ERZdtsa3N@ChDBfz8BwF1D3wDcsKwdkBmIllDvAsvOXLEP86ik4hsCx8HwIWdmd7e1xEOtxbA8p4cqVvEh2Pr9AfH3sY29N3a/iGZ@F7Hm52Yut8XezYonjp5PHLQwKxWXkn5ewk7pq7R/2C7xkdBME@fl2cN7h7CMR2VFsgE1weBhiI3WSKSoE7FZKEoNAXGGQrLMRYLFQQ1CL96XDIzhTib/h8dDTQkaPOqkFvCtmAzryGDUt@g1Z8D@3JghQ4HEqPeRzuHjQCecA2WD3SBkdL7t8n4WOzBfHmLkBRMIR7k9cQaIVTIH4HTgEHcvkGbBSYZESAt3tYggcBFght/@sIhYdpRKiQfyOzMzVq6UtexvVkn50hQ7lJjA3Uxb17b/Kt7ZAh@KOhI9SHsvkPmXAkrZMHR0@Onz87fPrk4ASuWmm7ymXwMIrvWoN6/CqEld9UT/C30n3Lobvehv5UM//kEwNCAwirwKTcAb56Y0A@ef4ZzAs@fyjj8WgQPZ5JAgO3fbceYzJ9@ntTX3W9s8KldW4VDhdONEIltsHu1@m7B@gJewffxIDTRnzbRnyyLTnY5uOMRR9EpzoX3toyNn0//Km4Er28hb6ghp7xG@NRNeiF4U/L6a5F9EYAusyP01qZbh551plF38gxYggW6tOfbgesOu0fHP4kfKAHOlo0V6sWi3VSlDGhRYlSlChHie0oUYkSO1FiN0pUo0QtTGgRZo1h1krVcnknSe4myWqSrMXJ7WKSTDBsl5JkOUluJ8lKkkyobcfUdqoUL8lE0qRdF8I1KNO2q1EZnnV1AppZATTacuY2MFpagYTq2yuZQK@6mAkz0ZDQ48IRApVKO8kzeJ8ItiUyrmTGh8wos6cwE8Yqjk0jqMEeeh54pcMZvrACjE6qEzx5xHHgdolhmzoEA2YAUUrrEdi/KdXZCVbvqh4PUiZiaGnxM1Q3YbYGdTS0otB81hSX1hUzbKW12NihYhILJhWEhUwyLuuLh6ooxu2FvDTWLXSwKNENECUGgTpIuLRTNJ9507UkyzeTXEC4luQKUwxvZV0tlI1IkbeiqnT8p9haET0Wp5hU2xAGhK9@ojawpFA8yty61ur8999@89/J99/@8rfku9/89v/8/X/E9N/h5X9CzEJKMcAvfomXv8HLf8bLb/Dyq1QlCl@u899987fw@B/@K/nuT3/Jiv7yd7y8HSOCEsxKav76z/DyM7z8L16uxIC//jkDxCq8POcWQisRoH7xj4QANcQSI/vm94TweQgwxNDyOqyP9yRpCUEshg5N9ZbL2dUYeSj2opSH4D4fPmnJUx4VIKWQezq@yyjpexDOsL1@9NKGbozwdF2Y5foY/xgYwri@egb2djmAoCeclwvQ@n9H6kTIIwxk0xPcLebDw/aH7eaTUoTN8wXgDp4jVJiWYk78K58D@6YzgStfxVmPRG2I2Ugo38/xXWnRAMJHlmUFIkyDQlpR7Y7WI@ELfuAvqiNTo8VhiJ2Apq9@4sKDYlqK4IK7WVIbUFnOyZPEGS1UpRnmeAIqgWqxvFGw@EClIC@jSzQXdpvDo0dLHQY/fQgxz9MeKSbUIjx/CyxKOoSXMOIqL8IzfkOATrFe7nHpE6PrgPkvv/yS51J5RbQhbyBSDKlGMZcRF2mLRaVUUSlVBDwznNTXVEqlJR7owIF@UVo@I7vooharJcaFPSfSA7IBc0G23iYP7ak/aq2iph550dmtIk@h1HqtsJ90Hepz2oSXVioAzsU6rWVdrkddXIFZVdT6mijthZwFbW3GtFAn1Smo9LhlKcWa02rrNLdI8AbUWi9/R0Kl4r@SkHJHQjuV2wktqxXrLqDfLN/b3U7kJmIPnyBjHT@zMEDh0PgNmF7ijpBjjyZFCaY8B@GUp3/pEnHNy6EgvxD9QmrhjVBe6ndTOIn53A1MtjywP3FhyuFiFJx6IeHzEHxh2sHe/3fmuJ7pp49uW@wAnCPgzwIM98yBUU3GX2pZ4bvJ8Mcs7Hdfi@NKPLKFUegD9o5DRM0EhZHn6anlWMHpKQSf9lBKBIiPqoHreAKHL0eEVKq@GIe2RxPRxd@XBtLtOGm8y6o9s4xz8WgSFgpA5IDAhM4wbZh8kZFunONrPqlIsIn0IDVGpP1AlFCII3fsnpmOiz@JwNpL6B8nuJEhfTKhvMhEl4mR4iicRIuGrEth1U8/uCr5tCTqUly/tIhgQRgy8ZZljJL11pA73UiOVYvonXw4vydpfk9u5ndoeX6wzDPNxNUevH8Y6bKYYADAhI3y7WzI4S@VVthZYCXOxpeusQp3ZnFg@gYMf8jpAYAehODqEOxDjp98eIoZ/2KT/G9WYFT98K7qo8HsyRX4m/Ehxn50iubTX346hikC@GMJfc8qudi0H96RVjjRoTM8mfDUcTl4uA065mRiOn68@RghvsXmrbPRig3RTLR9vK/hybuQyXlps4oeng5MW78yB2IIKafwRi1@auoD6q/u1nB0dNTpuexNe2JR1hZCMXoImQLVN5iMLl9I0mazYiBWbD10n4ty@Hiz/OjC3bJrxkXQFtuqcT3woBn6E0D6w8vJ1eSK/XzBZu@HDf0oG3@YJj/HX3XcKhCQA13WFjU5ISvd5D6finGT7jAixLDqYpPxbHKEEU8Hr@rww0R0e0vpKkNcqRVpeSE62aRx6yaNp6wiskkWldzNJG8zujvbXMrUGLLEhT34sCFkBfMD3bYNQ0xjZDk3asx1VnwC5qHGXGfDqHK6xqHGNamnC/BNWS0WX0icBcnHcL@A@xdwR4QwBz1lBhW1DePaaMmLloz1SSpqCXM6BsaiKSlK6X3EFBQXpXEhdx7TNDbSNFZoGgs04x6wSDIFxBkLJEMtoHpuUoFtDoMN3hmLcOYOt5vcNnwcV/dwT/hasIS6JRPhQqiDQxZMoX4oglMWBkL9IU34Qv2EJs6F@qeQSPqW8E6oR90CATx4pIl9zA9dOD4bQv2BKM05@lbwiK4q1GOdAswee6QSmbPlVYga6VKIG6@qmqbMgkqZoMX4cHOxWZ2eTL9F@KOg4e/qoXCrRUo5CowTkIVBIzViMDowbKj0Jc/iuuGjHi1NhesbyRoKlOdbqUUVtJIp9UdCRlh0RowxLKWLj3Dfwk13R6iv54hoKzOz29gJqYOFUiXXl/bcQXoqjQcGIi3vAHB6EcdO6kf6WkTBFHg3PrHyJj5X2InIUY7w1IC0hi0U6mvhhkahrhd5CbWf1tDqGgEqUYlAmJYo2pRPhxgOY1NKbOJOFo2EluJun5Wug5@wU6L1LlWjXiHsmRuKaXbYMnQM6c4v3dScVD1kbcEFYWGn2GO9LB4XqC/GosTXpSJV1vmAhZTPGdBfdplotg/DJIVj7kamY8WmYSiqy0hSz7XoJqGyiqesp3rAqCf7Mnj2@sOmr1FNCMGBR0SQqhlTYf7V/YD43WXxexRQR0JYIrAusF4/lK6G1zeOskuc2wnZVQVioUweSmuDo5hCInKYHaQi85tsbSXEx1ensiCfEY2xL0X7kdjiOcEtclueWzBcGCV4F4uZ57gwe17aLKjViMS@UKOgRUVKIR7W8JjTpGk388oavk7FWIJjNNw@WMHeooLTykN8tAHekshZL8cXkdN9irhvR8fOwp0Ltuvg4im2@O0JqUxw9/SHheFuhYwZR6dPHx59/tmfwKC7u7srrW5FYK@Fusk4zt24TRBPW0oy/rKV/u8aeHZi5HrBVtfhV3wJc9YQDOh034aZX9jHpdCXpfz5Ut@Fegw2JdEQ13nSDfQFr4Shjo5DthXKNQCBmIGY00MkUXgL8pbpbA13jdA6cEPn9JQOX6eneDjn9DQcxVA18TbS/wU)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)

### Explanation

Unlambda is an esolang based on the [SKI combinator calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus). Its commands are:

- `` ` `` backtick indicates function application. `` `FG `` applies F to G
- `i` identity function. `` `ix `` = `x`
- `k` constant function. ``` ``kxy ``` = `x`
- `s` s combinator, this is the same as the applicative instance for functions in haskell. ```` ```sfgx ```` = ``` ``fx`gx ```
- `c` call with current continuation (call/CC). Honestly, I don't understand this command.
- `.x` identity function that has side effect of printing to Stdout.
- `e` exit command. Terminates the program when it applied to an argument.
- `d` delay evaluation. Delays evaluation of its argument until it is forced.

All the multiple argument commands are curried, so partial evaluation is possible.

Unlambda also has `#` line comments.

The interpreter we are using has been included in the test driver because the interpreter on TIO crashes on characters that it doesn't recognise.

The program I started with as a base for the  answer was

````
`e```.1.0.6i
````

So i tried embedding it in the before any Unlambda commands appeared in the non-commented lines (this seemed like it was necessary for how the interpreter works). This means i had to fit it in with the dc, 05AB1E and tcl. My first attempt was

````
[  "`e```.1.0.6i]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
````

This has the problem of `.0` being the instruction to throw a divide by zero error in 05AB1E. So my next attempt was

````
[  "`e```.1'.0'.6i]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
````

But this has the problem of i opening an if statement in 05AB1E. It took me a while to work out how to close the if statement. It turns out we need a closing brace to do this. So next attempt was (forseeing the problem mismatched braces would cause for Brain-Flak)

````
[  "`e```.1'.0'.6i{}]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
````

This caused Brain-Flak classic to fail. My next attempt was

````
[  "`e```.1'.0'.6i]{}56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
````

dc was not happy with these braces so my next idea was to put the braces after the `q` that quits dc and quit 05AB1E separately. I could use the if statement to hide the bc from 05AB1E. I also needed a something falsy on the top of the stack for 05AB1E. So the final code ended up being

````
[  "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
````

Comment: I have to ask, it `␌` the character `␌`, or is it a literal form-feed? Same with `␉`, is it the character `␉`, or is it the literal horizontal tabulation?

Comment: Literal form-feed, literal tab and near the bottom are some literal escape characters. The test driver pretty prints the source like that for us.

Comment: It might be simpler to replace `i` by something else - it's never evaluated, so literally any function letter works there. (Also, I'm slightly disappointed you had to use a non-standard interpreter, but I guess putting the code at the beginning of a line is too hard on other languages.)

Comment: Come to think of it, `\`e` might be redundant - Unlambda programs are self-delimiting.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen this interpreter will exit with a non-zero exit code if i use any command other than `i` as the argument to `e`. Also i used the e command for 2 reasons: the earlier we exit, the better and I needed to use an even number of backticks.

Answer (score 7):

## 109. [DOBELA](http://web.archive.org/web/http://esolangs.org/wiki/DOBELA), 3503 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[       _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                           _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1k4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"arY\"[2]==89and 2-93or 4"))^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                x_
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002704 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3599 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIkthzI/wP9qUEchoACYAEKUr8ljTd6t2e6R7Jre6Z2SbZahAERbRAgAOAEtVqdqxf7nbWF/Z5b72xN3feud2wIzbCfjqHI85xG@EI3@v9ivkDnn8wzqzCF78k9Z7NFoFCVVZmVmZWVtYH0X3dH/3wQwY/5Ni1r85sNyCB6Qdk4FkXpqeSj6/Ivm75lVKZ4yiU5w6mhuWckWBkEsuZTAMytGzT5ww9IG0yCbGomCAZ4pn6gIFxQ9cjWIWMz21iEWMyIX1bH6kGsS2AfVSsEnPsvrHIWyjPEN8dI3RgehPPhKtPHNMcEH9iGtbQMihVYs4C0/Et1/FVYhnn5NKybTIwbaiQsGLIgIxM/VQWI6xyA5cj8DEmS4zHT1kTYBwzarw50T3aeJdMqCQiGVx6@mQCTHIZcgKMB9bY9IkVCD4xdd9CiUIV33QGVG6TWNYu0Z10K8mFpRMd@J16FLdvegE0T6V4ycj0TECpI/EzTx8T8dKzAhABivWAHJu6R557pikBFVCH6Rv6BPhYIAnEXKQQYENUqrZmUzg8eiSA@lgNVZ8EXMYrP//Xn3A6UVske9qAb4vnG9zhZw/JdbaLaeACkIGKJ56oS6T1nviFbteE70zrF868OQdYOZCKTQruJCjoygQYVAJgsKBjElPKRUmd2CnCpLmki5RRMagBaIM8dsjnMm2ZMfU8E/hIhKqfQ6Nt1zkDeUJjvamD8nDIThFUYLjOwJeJeQFScx2mI/eSSvj5yAKl@agSvQ8C0g2UPesQVKDQJcD2QolGdH3XnlI4qOkHaIAgFaiKGB8PyedkqFs2VoFyRMW49kx/agdYZ@oMUPNjyzEHKonYMNwBAo3dCyCnA1KaAX1onOp5lCkABkW4tKlY9N1f/s3g7AzwHBiG6w1Cc/2cDFxjOgaGdcqsDqaIBus6uk3ZAjgZqbPqQOBCt62BHiB55yokQZmgVC/dqT0gLhD0Li3oWiP9ArrjcGgagcmM3J0GwKNMxvo58xcWs1xo@Fjvg2IpAUqbNlsh@w9AS4bJTEYZT4NhlSiTQyL4hVfiXl3c2@qawJukSrlsoXDWAHtTczQLnoSbDOfzg0SfaD3PLRf7kT0ZTcFrQInjT8CfeChMQ4fm@OhWAvCBMulTQVNfBKZOO@mlKXgm6UPPjhpGbYTZANZXsOeGGBKdRnCLJmYOUhYG1glGFvgrbsJ2L4Ew5Q0dKdi0g8T1Mx1IBWGDDliDGEWas9i0cwcsHbH1TVJV@hZoB@0AnE2ojFQbAbxcYjCAjWkv1SnG@hVgMZiTTjRJrCEoeQx2610Rw8TOAL3CZJ4OiUypYfgW2JE7JEWlVKncovzAKxwoL8F7vC3cqGNs/JKaD8jQvCS27pxN9TMwZNeBKrphmJMg7EHQEj@APrLsCGmmEnp11R9x2f1l2tS7hf4@RQO9D9Ne6KN1NHsQ1BhErdjQy4nundGeSAaWB/3FvlqmDgAXS8T51wiywMBrfgML0dAERmbOTGMaQHcDQ74cWcYIbBe5c1iHZd5xmTxkpamDy1GGMWlkRmvfL3FqIc5CNjaiUFCjq3jA6yOq9kIGVX4642bMuj9eg9iNWQQPlcpVC7oKthcKDcbzE4wlwP1FgzftWXGAEcsTBAxdHbopGMsoCCZ@HdyNFYymfRXUWnjuXT0OjhzUbCHwrqzAZem@7fYLY92HzlSIKBSMad@aLbWI5sUCf@NzFzCMD33SAv//1RRMRBSGviA1aP4DBE4V8XRopSjYlQdACqSCpMShr2II9gg8wMmVY4i8Su1ehR7Cy4THXsZLkMBasVweuGN0GeQLOrxgvPCxB25mCK6Fm1wFI5CDYhBeb7kT0xGFBaMUJEpQlBo0OhAE9Y1rOeK1sLW1JdSFtiBDag9STUztYSoPqT2aUmgK4VRM0RoyTWFph9bAvJ4w70SYZ1IP1TbDEOitNRH1Tr1e7sl6RwvvJbxL4JfADQG0gjfAI0itFiYliW9fQkPV/pC1/hmT7IBawzPTOePM2cT1AvLZ0cPD0@OD5z9p8YWp7xVsq19wYEA8HUN3gxCYX1MfYtmoOiSfuW7QogrDfAr9OB3hDj13HHsHnzONkUv4bJnHyAxDYwUdyhjjtslVVLqNpVPH1sf9gY75FO1zcEBPIAIiTywcmIYLdLhYYF2OZwotL7oWPikpseDtAkwZ3OTkav2gyqdR0QrA5rmLfShJnRZVrbKAAqYCqzWHlj@ilwXQFbZWS2htf9wf0ssagHo4KsIQi5MGlMsnGHLiwOy6MMG4pGBj13EZKyAvy9ELz@hNBWe6jp9Fn7XATN8cTiEMLfQtB9O3gCm1KoUc9vvWJlCQC7Ie3deAedP@OrGBCxutDGtkQfDB1AtscxDe//lnA1DAqnpG@pUP8e15nDgFuaGqlOFGbYVV8YFe1mv2zdSG2c8tOAwdY1rdjhPrcWHHJIoy0j3Q5lWkTbBGvICTvc3eoavY04EZ3dcToTJdHC1ZbccaU03CHYd@6k03VF8a61l9nBN4tqsPKBY2V7PMRL1MEeZMP4PGFVLzR9Xr34HPaEgmyeQMhrNgyq44H7tNkdYEvzd10BCyWNH7mllwfb1vbZAiMrGzyZBZ/8DhRxna@jlLnmJyfVNZYzzrDCZ/0X0TGAREELNOdMMsXNLbRp/iTP0JUwWmbsDn2ey6CcRyDAh9nSSxCRCaadPLh5gdNQQD@gayiushSkpE1pJQbb1/hUP06MPtBwme5fNEAX/SMvL5YpkobjJdSVZeJpPN9Q0jrF@rra/NFmkoAsOFmaV5W5@FgcYa67ZSGqSSG31uFNIkqXUuSb/QIdixdR8MJAjFbF6AWujlJqPFscOY2rqXpG4w2YSdaFa6aWKT1JlYhmtboWVGD5t84XKUmaDB5Td6Sari06p8BxDY4bisxKn1Hdo1ApxcbLCjO7gnFtfjzCllGKq7SXaGe4nfjb135F6Y7Lp@jHq7lqs7uB/FppYBk4XV6gPjNnPFdRN6WS/F87VcBYa9Nr9OnrquBxM7n5TUIkY0Dl3sgxHattnc5fnjo8027Vu265MTer1JFhCB@j67rrfmtNgs3VGMEetjcXp9tbVM0eGNHNDrBuXq9plr71TPCjpcNlrA1Builw/vd/VwsYfStFs9VBzfuI4W3je69nP4u804cMEAfLmFgU6cXG8oG91ZOK3Z3ECYB@AC0frGPSpWY8vyfPNGk2Kq8IzRpX4V3f@EcWSTnKNxZHJF42SI67BCrQqJwGOx859CbftmaoO7easVtLu3NSKl5nPbBN9NryvKJaWi9oE1tGLx7r5raE/NqbnWlxz135hgQDep/O5MFcNmZMMZcAGEh3s8MdTbcBZ4J65xZMenG12PblvQ3W@Na9Y6nQnE2hOcOh9D4hgTqxXPnOlkQbkp2T2bOs9ultxoEvVxd7DAJJZ8qG@q3h49LQTkvkm/611JnRyOXZjrumOIJpw76D9ESlcn2HUBMc1JML@xHkAo4t2It07iFS2IZCEyAa1a574Coc/GMWDR8ZQ2TdIpcK0GszLHDK7wukna61xq33XtD9EOeNaBhQEbhKG42Xmblurk5GrchxjOSJbb7qCBaMII0sLJ8UbFHgPK4I44y6vLTTeMV6nFp7WUf@za7Wb7FqU/w76rqVV19xbAh0cfHz45uAkoXIaju37xMrwvh9uVkGd54eaUH@8AZx47hmfSRflo3ZdkcKtgOobAPXA9lVA4UdTzeUniWCWM/c4cAIug6B4cboOw7T2fQEQeUFhrSDodkr2e1Yt1bU5ahK/zpNdjWOmC/OFsQjfPnrGqnazea2UFRRGyQtepk6JAQU0bhuK1oPoC3NCiN8Zn0nTi6GO684LpqKUNtr0DETLu6Y10Z2Cb5AVYFJ03uB7bpGA7Yc9xbeif/jAItzrPTGjk2PLB4Z45uD3vjs2Re7nH6IbUDyYTHbdKEQfMjm22P6I8OCD@pRUYI7bDCQH8i0fPq@H2VHhwAB6OseumuGBKRWMGHvSAKY1xM3BNZhYh4bhW1CiYIk3HDrm0BsHIVyHcdQyTbn/Fi66QQjAn8Fw0K5k8JgMTp@oDZOzNFHRru@45XdxFTv7pD2xTDgotNCFMR@TpLnGKIkETpzthhuFOgesIyVvTc0MQEYUME70p@j4wapPlS8QY6XS3ECxRifbKkAzbL3twcEKUQyLgKQdc1G9YQzF78OzHn3eKvdZ7Mi6Y//yzgnQdyo3/SNnVfF4mEUhjjnaVLi5CcVIqED4748Nm4X463T6OjYr1JiJimqor2vsa0614anfmJd37ohucDrpF3ON2fOgf8ChR1KzTtLLi1LbGVkCUk4BU8CiICSKBFNu8J3i4AvdxsEp2Rt6REdqKYhCtUoQnJhAbtw7HrY@jldVyegW88NDsT@nK0EVJLZVbtDnZ0xZ4KUx55sDFzeXOq@5lr@BHUul2Zx8VSzMQm@sB@P0C9pzDzx5eZ9V28d07H0Jenp8LDbYwD907e338@Pjw5PnB8xcnIMY5a2XmkeuN9cRFoBFMbJiWjFyb7taDPDzL9G93G/eo3@DuhYCiSLI6aUIQSMBD3YsdSyhWXuGzLMnKqCeJy5YKQ/cxtEjo6sgx1XaoWMFPuzk5MgAUHvTJKfjViHkwnOs17oo2hyctaJACDaLgMcPx07qGLZZSeCbwPXwGoYfNSEPRpiZQ64GwrQw45JvBMCbXNmL@/4jzCYwjt3OOULdxDsDcbdRThB8dPH7y4tnhKu0U2RBmBSS2kNQBqcMZBD3gB4fUwnETPrIbNzxEETkG8PsjttWq24lr88mF5Vt926SWNETHbEPfxk5B12d97NwE/YhKDmwfHOlgAJ6hfxWgYwGPqtJdMbY1pjiEz4AA1HickwnPIazfWt1MB8dxCUGb8ZpVzlI4itlfdx6laxa@@8u/YWdQugGkvw7TQ0j/BUu/KqCAVg8tMB5j0aBYPn98THwYrVjDx/os1SYcMHBAshyYrFljkOAFFQiCM2aT9iZ4xM7nIE9QAggTPR86O0rP9Hoi7mLXCwUc389ce6jSbRxzBnoAX0k3tb@a4pEg8M@FncrOtlYAJpWLCKFiMYTKhCGUpDqYEHdhTVqv@wZpNpuE9yF4N1s7DSbIQlZ/VeZfx4xmAZZjoUCHQB2oktSAsnZYTczqeU3CqtgLBU0gvQaM8kwvMFCINAEgEmY7oTx4GIncUFSgdMecBdSpXkUhDsQXjkvGKCd6MCxCpAAihlviuRXbTbYLcOs0Zc1qWg38Fwh2gmB1fp3pdF6RbtB1euEJJgIG83drDMmB9C/WHGuKredg9fSSuHz2CFtD9k8cFzeQHgG3RCwVSuWCtiOlegofogJ@sV@8A5TQE6BnGab1xp34Bw8OH39ydHyycvqGQgrLYAIR2s18V1HlTi9OCEtWHwn140eFk6cfP4pEmeYqmX8hRDIJW2ZzHbVlTjdQ/4Lt1azSpgUrhLTiXRHTGZzyiK5TrGJPSgspwAdsLXmFqihdzzu9ZrvrZFbIv1t3Vi6j5tC4INX16Uk5gazxOY@jHajn7jnYixodKCjxyUFQg6NTWTd8TrI3n8kJEJv1Nn10KNrrwnM5pXZhYF4UnKltc2qyC8ZnxeZCyyQeJKAWGEF6NIWxF3ENHidiWEOGE7IGt7KfkOaJhC2KSadrxjpCUR2xOSI9Jqg7MD3wYGpOoX3qptlMkp5pg7nE4yCZfsCUBufZdJZ1RWcU4DDi9fmBRfdxdC86wxGXnJhjS3ke8YPuIzltA@4MT5GMoG221W/orc6MxOc4bjqIo/oT2wpEPAEzU3GmBq0RJWyA1rRNPEDTrPXC0zokOlSTp@dyjqcgr2N3QpLZ8UMzSj2DCRJ5OAXkYAwm@WQ6BrghvT0zcawwyWeuApVBjkLERAeoiGEb1PGgAtTVkTkbWGcw3oiSDI7pI01LTvToUh5mtQJ4YyaqH@PGQ1owH3QKKSUxvaOrljMwZ6JwKUj1HkoH8oXLLy4EiV@xAXoUKjwXNVg@ExW5DD0I@25ynmjJLdRqsTtY7EG1mjryOTxiAzE@UDwJvCeQhJFUHI71CRGn9FCZT1RCH8Wu6Mh@4ElEaeOodkkcks/T2QHcaIFKaM0hTVk2nukU8SSvWGiBnjHXdwZ4e2tNSEdT1R6kKRGJZHFi/wCCDpwSSxyEklClTtHCMAz/6sjRJcyDkCN2z1KyHM7KPYBaW0w78tmIdkCQBW01ad8niU9IeiCTaq1WD7Wx6BRrBMxidTxSC4B2jbOL4k6Qb3hsAqSGrgygHsB8zwKHsv@p6TjQX0WwmTH0TqJPwcg8SY5@AiHHh1QzlEKGsfiT8BwGMJpZcMeHwrXtQlSTLTTo5LIxh9H/dReH/2EYAFwVflRQC41rMWu3rgoQkkltMTtqaflyLp/POjkx62BQcv8@zknnWYh5TlVe5WcApGRtqQH2DDFSK@s0snpTzA5apRytAY/5vHQNFd77BfU6q88L2fsQU8iQ47HeKWZ9CbtDUVW1OfCHPSRbkMFmrkWe8DM87ovks1Y@jzyo2VNk4H2he5Kno0v3pEBnwY0w1C2cjSM3sqCWH37IaDsw69rbKYvuXqm8lcuQzD5fyHUfvnz54KIhdPRhSf2qd3x@fPyl1BWFzIMjXtvmGyRX4DKFXPHdbqHw@vVrCAJJp6221Z7UUYReR2zv7uYa8k41J@/LmiA3MsTWipomiaWSdNLd1fVcfru07zQsy5r4gwF83RHEvBAKtVBB9@AjaseCUCkLJ6/wCOLeFvyjf/CJH/G6RXPCbAqy@tmSiPjVjMu074FRlXe29u8Bw2aefur1fToZ4HervOvuc5n3XOaKy7xuvuYyEPxm2u3efJ5XOuqrvKqe9vJKvtlpNtV2e9ZWeu1OOOc6JVzmmsvM5lymxKMAc1ymNWs@oyQ6D9uMVv4rAH0C96bS60yOnxwenBzKpaaSKT06eCCXTl58nNHgqZI8YmEZH58dHjw8evFcLrFaP378@eGLY8j3e6ft/f28qijKvtrudYCHj/LtfCsIAvLyNKeSzZ/TNSn2yGUetmcvCkoTWH0S5jyjNJQuPHUloPSOy3QyHXGvtFcq2sWLonaunW8f7RztP3WPkr@jIyi0ZsU3rlccFUfaQNO0WdF8UbwqXs2KY/dIG0DShH/FMSSt4nBWPCs6RUfTFvBs/hsfuU@PXEDlQrVgVgwQa3EI97Ojo6eAbAiE38A/q1hEJmfFC/gr2hr9vDotEiIVu12uQ/jXJtiyqglqUVB3BMHqVXYmX13PSztfdehQU6n1OubMCno8kYXTbqdWqwm9Rqbgd7sF1r/4EnQOBJnPT08fHjw/OD0t4Px71szm9/PKPnxa7XwzvO1lBm2Uqtrc6nKCePnFF1/g94vLi0uWogmW90VcmH6gCfhcbKi7mNhgB6LYqfSu55Ik3esKDYG1RBRNiJ9EXuvOSkNS4mlYUgOnpJVx6NupSO32TgWed6qSIhaxlFXo8rr30y7fKfVarWoN80tKrQyA27wkvdKazbBuSXI9XpjxrieQ63nyT7yeN0X6kfCfJGFmeG1LIhRLFXiaXYuzptgUMQ@ysNb1vI1JCncNqY4o9aT5nOXBVZSaDGdbAnHgPPP/05/rE39ChMw8gwOWQ7YrEsxiTWl7R6zma@G/1hY0RuTLQhnayAu60Ons58q53e3OXi/Xy4nNnJrrtnuz9EcSMgRMNTKtlpZBCXIZtfGM10q8gKbWwLVb1zZVG@aU5VpjUdfCqZhb/lS1Wj6X3@/kajVGO5d7twW9AtABMR4@GTBPIpJmuxnbTIJSasP3moQCh/T8GsyIlcH4J4aLtN3urFik8I1@K3ud0ecNip7MeaGxYI0UvSg06Oo9f81nda@j9fg5n73uzzFOyGkSHd8r241Gbpuld6sNGJW0XFhShJIwCQWmrxu0W8JAhJYlgMglaFSrb55ZDsQGCzLKVyqVQgmus492DkszroGr3GxJnVd41j1ItUYRZojv1zgIRfug@EuyW4Sphm3rHnGHwy2WDzE16ZsmhDWmbeP6EIacEHnZg0uY5mxxGXAjEHBBMXzGx7o5Nc3L6fTSjD8PLL@uv3kDMyb6@f7b3/wZfP8A31@y@y//W62C1@@//Q//5bvf/g4y/xG@/xO@//D9t3/9M/alz3@E7/9K5f0x/Kbg2JcDXP/2@29/9fvvv/2Lb@D7n8LvN8vf73799@zvf4f/MPm77379R7ywB8D1m19899c/BxZ/jek/hzT8hdlfh8lULkt@HSWh3t8uAf/i@2//6vdh@udpkFQ@VP0a8n@byv@a41CZW6SyK8uqqsIF7zL90LuafRWBaJsHzwz3FJeoahrbsLOwBqQ8s8b9BMxgPDVGuA9qBRgnwQSmyKloNKVSrVqp1sqlqlytVbcr2k6lImslWdut7taKMoRIVW2nWqlpcnW7Vt7e3q7JRCtVarsQ0DoDa1goQFih8TyhCZgn4wHoJh4dd9VRm8sMzCHMEu6RmTiQ7mUGUQaZVglfrnaLMDOnExmRSOQahzSR@DCfBc7FojwFR17Zm1b5nV2@noM7v8eXIUkbPBNJUYDuywtdnpc6td4ev1vh6xCaKcJ9bY/wuzWY4ezu8lKDr/D8Dint8vxLsHbzTBHIbI9vzIHnSBhxawgMfqpK4KsoHJZPWowhka@JhPaLWpdnXoN1QUEUhN2SIEhCA5Bs8WmtSA1sHTSOtS1ijge5AnM1GMQanhlMPUesKeCCiVKTGnPG0r9K8eSdw3xK93BOQ0nWCb9T4zEbQJpiDUm1K/1cXdYUeZ9j/mBH4zJzboDHPLdrpFFrYDwIY1azzWUFZEsocxml7G67mWw2C6Hl8zZf5o/U02YhjA3bBRoYdjFWxFBLjeJP8K8FzjNx@2mAv@5l43O1gq05I34m/yd@VCDRApxcA108n5mwQeYKI2HSZSw132foIRxyfB3tLkwdukhSf4qy1usn9Ah8p0ek959Z9nW1rLTp5A5m@HMC0p2f1F7tvqq@evri6MXRo/1ivVqvdrvLHWoGEab/TnIr2nvnk0amPhHK20IZQs1WhjVX25Uy7dKu6utXmV64bS5u70oEnqifL2mZIYZCScS0EimlUmueLy/GNEwHRqo/GpydWaUfPX39LlsoCAIhWnbnvdJkf024PDhiahf5nQov4XED/9Xpq9MMeHPClypolvkCCR12enSb5Rz6z8z59J9pJhk@PEZPWG5KOZh4flkCt1Gr7VR3MtwPhcJN64RQGk@ZhyZMJafjdXPmA896quN6ghPPmyHxdPrW9GKvQtCt4FIQ@pV0XuhqUln05@qQxyFftAdiQvfODJluIJEc/pKi0wOfE20@iliK@19SvF3GeiYpNti2JqKwGnESqKBjIC0EoGYIEaVotbQGsZqIDO4wrQ4p4CeqkW9hEpfTKBdWT2pw6X1Aykkbaqd4SdXP5xn4nLHF2mOMB6zZrCx@BPbGeF7CEMPa0hJAp9jDZZpuUQibeZdmGHogxhhk8sHNWKrPE16K2kRZSArD/EQVcy4XyOMGh83OTRrcp6IhXePKRuP9@P5949WkM@41pHErwHs@PwZ3ei5aDCQXtMYtRWtMgNlG0MnnrV5rLH0qTijz41YRgIE2Yval61jTTitUly/JbzuO8t7pyY86Tl7ryVM597L1VtZbRXkGXxCbbMtfgfAiUYpB623eaehN@OIiy4IkYGjJ643F7Vmoci7arbcdvdcqSg0bKubzj6AxwKffsfP5ngTEbShcrdiw79/X83Z71rAVRUKoV@W9R50AEr18C5/rot6c7b3tTKF@XYR7C8jYEjAP9RZ1APiAvwbImKkvYZ3xOEP2ZsDeuNXKvdzLvcy1trbedmbKuCcz8deLieKR@Rkyn7YRMfcybVhUJDQ0F/mPrPpHas4nvAzWB0KWJ6majMPcSyiZJL1hjq6I/nY@WsDDZd1wX5b9XJL@pI2ux@O7MPC0iYt5eEAE6h74hmWF4Oxkz8QyB/jLAsuXIZh2FJ1CYFn4dgks7M729riIdLhpCJTxSE7fJDqey6E/5fZwokDfVOIbnoVvzbjZia3zdbFji@Kok8cvDwnEbOWdlLOTuGvuHvULvmd0EAT7@HVx3uDuIRDbKm6BTHDdG2AgppMpKgXuVEgSgkJfYJCtsBBjtFBBUIv0p8MhO6GJv4j00dFAR446qwa9KWQDOvMaNiz5DVrxPbQnC1LgcCg95nG4e9AI5AHbYPVIGxwtuX@fhI/NFsShuwBFwRDuTV5DoBVOgfgdOAUcyOUbsFFgkhEB3u5hCZ5wWCC0/S8jFJ4SEqFC/o3MDguppS95GRfKfXY4DuUmMTZQF/fuvcm3tkOG4I@Gk1AfyuY/ZMKRtE4eHD09fvH88NnTgxO4aqXtKpfBUza@aw3q8YslVn6hPsFfnvcth27nG/ozzfzpJwaEBhBngUm5A3yRyYB88uIJzBc@eyjjYXMQPR62AgO3fbceYzJ9@utdX3W9s8KldW4VDhdOh0IldnLAr9M3OdDfKzj4Xgucg@K7S@Ije8mJPR9nMvogOiG78A6csen74Q/vlehVOPR1P/Tw4hjP4EEvDH@oT7djovcr0P0LnCPLdFfMs84s@n6TEUOwUJ/@ED5g1Wn/4PAH9gM90NGiuVq1WKyToowJLUqUokQ5SmxHiUqU2IkSu1GiGiVqYUKLMGsMs1aqlss7SXI3SVaTZC1ObheTZIJhu5Qky0lyO0lWkmRCbTumtlOleEkmkibtuhCuQZm2XY3K8MitE9DMCqDRljO3gdHSCiRU317JBHrVxUyYoYaEHheOEKhU2kmewftEsC2RcSUzPmRGmT2FmTBWcWxeQQ320PPAKx3O8PUfYHRSneCRKo4Dt0sM29QhGDADiFJaj8D@TanOjuZ6V/V4kDIRQ0uLn6G6CTM4qKOhFYXms6a4tK6YYSutxcbONpNYMKkgLGSScVlfPC1GMW4v5KWxbqGDRYlugCgxCNRBwqWdovncm64lWb6Z5ALCtSRXmGJ4K@tqoWxEirwVVaXjP8XWiuixOMWk2oYwIHyRFrWBJYXiGe3WtVbnv//2m/9Kvv/2V78j3/32d//nH/49pv8eL/8dYhZSigF@@Su8/C1e/iNefouXX6cqUfhynf/um7@Dx3/3n8l3f/YrVvRXv@fl7RgRlGBWUvM3f46Xn@Plf/ByJQb8zS8YIFbh5Tm3EFqJAPXLfyQEqCGWGNk3fyCEz0OAIYaW12F9vCdJSwhiMXRoqrdczq7GyEOxF6U8BPf58ElLnvKoACmF3NPxzVBJ34Nwhh1iQC9t6MYIjw2GWa6P8Y@BIYzrq2dgb5cDCHrCebkArf83pE6EPMJANj2a3mI@PGx/2G4@KUXYPF8A7uA5QoVpKebEv/I5sG86E7jyVZz1SNSGmI2E8v0M3zwXDSB8ZFlWIMI0KKQV1e5oPRK@Lgn@ojoyNVochtjRbvoiLS48AaelCC64myW1AZXlnDxJnNFCVZphjiegEqgWyxsFiw9UCvIyukRzYbc5PHq01GHw04cQ8zztkWJCLcLzt8CipEN4CSOu8iI84zcE6BTr5R6XPgq7Dpj/8ssveS6VV0Qb8gYixZBqFHMZcZG2WFRKFZVSRcAzw0l9TaVUWuKBDhzoF6Xlw7@LLmqxWmJc2HMiPSAbMBdkK3Dy0J76o9YqauqRF53dKvIUSq3XCvtJ16E@p014aaUC4Fys01rW5XrUxRWYVUWtr4nSXshZ0NZmTAt1Up2CSo9bllKsOa22TnOLBG9ArfXydyRUKv4LCSl3JLRTuZ3Qslqx7gL6zfK93e1EbiL28Aky1vEzCwMUDo3fgOkl7gg59mhSlGDKcxBOefqXLhHXvGoL8gvRr80W3q/lpX6DhpOYz9zAZMsD@xMXphwuRsGp1zu@CMEXph3sbYpnjuuZfvpMusVO9jkC/t7BcM8cGNVk/NWbFb7pDX@lw35@tjiuxCNbGIU@YG@MRNRMUBh5np5ajhWcnkLwaQ@lRID4qBq4jidw@KpJSKXqi3FoezQRXfy1biDdjpPGu6zac8s4F48mYaEARA4ITOgM04bJFxnpxjm@NJWKBJtIT4hjRNoPRAmFOHLH7pnpuPhbD6y9hP5xghsZ0icTyotMdJkYKY7CSbRoyLoUVv30g6uST0uiLsX1S4sIFoQhE29ZxihZbw25043kWLWI3smH83uS5vfkZn6HlucHyzzTTFztwfuHkS6LCQYATNgo386GHP4Ea4WdBVbibHyFHatwZxYHpm/A8IecHgDoQQiuDsE@5PjJh6eY8c83yf9mBUbVD@@qPhrMnlyBvxkfYuxHp2g@/QGqY5gigD@W0PeskotN@@EdaYUTHTrDkwlPHZeDp/agY04mpuPHG5IR4lts3jobrdgQzUTbx/sanrwLmZyXNqvo4enAtPUrcyCGkHIKb9TiZ6Y@oP7qbg1HR0ednsveWygWZW0hFKOnqylQfYPJ6PKFJG02KwZixdZD97koh483y48u3C27ZlwEbbGtGtcDD5qhv22kvyidXE2u2O8ybPa23dCPsvGHafIz/LnKrQIBOdBlbVGTE7LSTe7zmRg36Q4jQgyrLjYZD11HGPHY86oOP0xEt7eUrjLElVqRlheik00at27SeMoqIptkUcndTPI2o7uzzaVMjSFLXNiDDxtCVjA/0G3bMMQ0RpZzo8ZcZ8UnYB5qzHU2jCqnaxxqXJN6ugDfO9Zi8YXEWZB8DPcLuH8Od0QIc9BTZlBR2zCujZa8aMlYn6SiljCnY2AsmpKilN5HTEFxURoXcucxTWMjTWOFprFAM@4BiyRTQJyxQDLUAqrnJhXY5jDY4J2xCGfucLvJbcPHcXUP94SvBUuoWzIRLoQ6OGTBFOqHIjhlYSDUH9KEL9RPaOJcqH8KiaRvCe@EetQtEMCDR5rYx/zQheOzIdQfiNKco@9Yj@iqQj3WKcDssUcqkTlbXoWokS6FuPGqqmnKLKiUCVqMDzcXm9XpyfRbhD8KGr4wAAq3WqSUo8A4AVkYNFIjBqMDw4ZKX5ktrhs@6tHSVLi@kayhQHm@lVpUQSuZUn8kZIRFZ8QYw1K6@Aj3Ldx0d4T6eo6ItjIzu42dkDpYKFVyfWnPHaSn0nhgINLyDgCnF3HspH6kr0UUTIF34xMrb@JzhZ2IHOUITw1Ia9hCob4WbmgU6nqRl1D7aQ2trhGgEpUIhGmJok35dIjhMDalxCbuZNFIaCnu9lnpOvgJOyVa71I16hXCnrmhmGaHLUPHkO780k3NSdVD1hZcEBZ2ij3Wy@JxgfpiLEp8XSpSZZ0PWEj5nAH9yZqJZvswTFI45m5kOlZsGoaiuowk9VyLbhIqq3hse6oHjHqyL4OHuT9s@hrVhBAceEQEqZoxFeZf3Q@I310Wv0cBdSSEJQLrAuv1Q@lqeH3jKLvEuZ2QXVUgFsrkobQ2OIopJCKH2UEqMr/J1lZCfHwRLQvyGdEY@1K0H4ktnhPcIrfluQXDhVGCd7GYeY4Ls@elzYJajUjsCzUKWlSkFOJhDY85TZp2M6@s4etUjCU4RsPtgxXsLSo4rTzERxvgLYmc9XJ8rTvdp4j7dnTsLNy5YLsOLp5ii18LkcoEd09/MRnuVsiYcXT67OHRZ09@CoPu7u6utLoVgb0W6ibjOHfjNkE8bSnJ@JNd@n@V4NmJkesFW12HX/ElzFlDMKDTfRtmfmEfl0JflvLnS30X6jHYlERDXOdJN9AXvBKGOjoO2VYo1wAEYgZiTg@RROEtyFumszXcNULrwA2d01M6fJ2e4uGc09NwFEPVxNtI/xc)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically, 97 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>, 107 [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7, 108 installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- DOBELA, 109 [local](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/dobelx64/)

### Explanation

DOBELA is mentioned in [A Brief History of 2D Programming Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829).
DOBELA has two interpreters: dobelx64 (Linux, console, author Deewiant) (see also [dobelx64 online](https://tio.run/##tXfbjuPIktjzEP6DfVFLvVZVsat4v3VV1zR1v1AiRYmkqKqaHt7FO8W71NMHfrL3rP3itbHYXdg72AUM@MFPfrLhAxjwp5wvmD84pqp6ZvrMOfNiwJHMZGTkLTIyMiJS17L9H/7Qae3zPMneQpBpWZWrRfmN67s3tgvZbmBlUJLGnmXkGWTGuhXUJP4Tcm0F9k1enwDL2Met9muk3bpv/bLxRtcyi8SBl1/r2vy1Hn9mLFCf/twAINfS1nVt/6JBSwFDy5tpkjg4OkGcA3/C8U9NrbtWs90SioogaESAkK1W@2sSu4i/RrFXV51W530bunoc7Hb98rb7oNnozeFJ8AVhe/l40e30@TaCt29bVxDQga7g7ygI@vbbb9vftloP9zf3N0@XD9fdp4eLe4q6un1D0ldv3r9Bum9uO60AgRHk8gJFL9ePlKZdgTj6Prp1XTfJTLPJ8d6ITTdy3hW5TX/VwAUidLsE1l1/0/26gVdNev4a@Kl6Ll89Uz6Tn7v8Kby6bF0caqBz/xXQaWHkq/dfNQxb4DO8ffu@1QDUpuh2HL8HOr8BOkeg8@3dt0Dn7u6uc3//9OkTeP1w8w14c/PhCbwG7x7u7m7u7@v766f7h9YLfGgBnY9Ap/4EdND2WYBXQOddfSc@L/EwuH9ZCzw0Xbnmf3f99JAI3JBdD9@gd9cddMT236BrqddBmhrxc/XciJ2r4pAd8NLmDfoyajyVh5LQ0LOnD/fv34M319fX72/unx4aHv4SvAff5Xne2n24umn9Onz4M9hLFegM7msJur5rWOU@U8TnNa4fm9rjZbPSd0DnofNw8TX6NQoHcAkjPuLjPMm/X8T8zx/PN41uDXtxCu/hPWIiCFLDlgQf4WMNhzGPmA1qNQkOG9SF7Rp24AiOEOSP5vn1L@TjBR83U8XNsLyG8/OssN38HZ5fNJPZzcJek1wYPjNZw2XzwQHyDN98gFutS/jxEXhotb@1Gl2@Qbo3cPeG7HbdJ4JMDh8/oeThISnyrEUwTw9W7eZP7dab7ofHB4Zhuk@3HSh7fIRuk9SN8jbaXI5zl0@fPnwYsBv2w4fmonQ69d1r8D14/b6Bd/fg3eff1x3z/izVm7tXj0D3olIU5ZyVqqxesGfkhab81Phl5RlpoPyVsX@M/IoeXFw8EE8fP11eXn712L3tvuzk4sIqteCijTzWqN1C25daZLaYOG0h2N1d64IkLu/vSaKpk/Tl9QV8bn0Z8NjWUvWx/YA@vXtHM2c6es1gTUe8fXn5DXJ393ksehmn7W7djtNu6@Onn9PFx093F89weU6Xl2fi5/L@8qJpviSaWv3xor67uLs40xrSedTHT/dn9LnfxwZ7uLh8uvz06YXWlBeXdy9z3l824mhF8f@vL85aWdLqdj51Ls6ybOHE5YV@tC5x8oIGmc/p3atmMxdtrIs1e2x3te7Dw/sr7IrCH75@unq6uri7url6vH@qv4TLbqfVqOqPqvUO6ZwlCHRubsU2gra7Z1W7NeIoiwPrJoidFsbc/vFZdz9cXP0SaIQBr8D3D1cM87L21dV3r5pb0UzXLNZuoNOoZ@uidXd/95PO/Dzl5X2TP7Y@C7zBP31s1OilTXv3@lkEud3wXcPwc/9b/d3rjx3t0@3z9K1P7e7tH2nj8/QX3VujcY6t9sf2ay19QJ7an9qvP@qfWo08r5DLZ79L4Le3V/gLTtG3jVdCrj63wE3LZ7RpsDLNeL6WjSM6a1a3Eflls6l3uuW4EdBJ/khGIEEQENqU9V@SQ7QGbjMrbz3votW@br9cjxbNPE/YaWUZAxR5ojcHX7UouPHMQdA46di2X73Q91rW0i0ramVWEDQerhUXeauK08CsXNN6BXQaM8K0mKa5gVDQrKIJRoqisn6Cvpu91TxPS17gh@//7l83@b82@W9e/n/z3xjiXP7w/b//L7//x39qiP@ryf@zyf/jh@///l@95Of675r8v7@g/e5z/qLfSwaauf7tD9//x3/@4ft/9w9N/s@f8z/8Mv/@b//7y/d/Pqcz@k@//9vfnYuXSjPX3/317//@rxoW//aM/5sGb77P5N9@Rr@gvqC//RFtxv2nX3T@6x@@/w///Bn/qy@7fEFvhv62of/jF/TfAsD5MF@1COrNm5ubm6Y4/988w/P/5vU3P3ZBft15doBFnFotBmnOuZXv3fOIBkstBpg0ahAWxr7lZi03P8dJrt2CgZuz0qAoQxM0g6H0G5qhcQIhCeINgr5BKJpi4DdNiEQjJE0wyBsaZzAcx5k3LQQlGAroWJHp2hDUhBVIu916RtzICArTusty041v9vdAx7RsN7K@atUX5uVXHfNHQqugW22MfoRbbSDUmgt00bpsfTy7tItW5p6shvML@E3RGHLi64Juk1T77VXzb3/dxhr0ecP1RQvuNte33X1sty8fmKev2xTRftuEZtfdf4l83WpTTPttm6Lal7dtot0mWyjVbu8abbec626r/rp9@6nh@Udh/LSbVuP8bm5aTb6@Bs7tybsXhi7azEXr@V4wj@0Xq/FyBbsX3S6FdruX3dtmklftL0/l8va8u2ZzL3v7kbl2I9eGOaZxYreplRdpdMFcNya4dc1c3n56YelffMFT6r/NmpA6b333suTbVptk2mdy0@XugjkvdU/oV2/fINdv3gMv9oBEgM4nwHQbw48zrVvm9hwPNj7r7h543T2z1cWAzjUW43Hn9evXTWi5uW9jbf7mwx30OTa8h54Dw8dzrHgOtW5@jD8b@woBqeW0muXftT8boAuaOO/GaWUd8P8Rbpol3jVzArdnE9/uJC9O5niOhFuPLyzd/aZjBFqWtYSPn4VsF5GRu3H0dnGWtfZ2nTfsOA9PrcvfLN3gI41d3wvPDDaybTXS/bRmvqG@ob9ZSLzEj97Db@m39OPjLy9U3USY2XeXMYH8Jprddt4mXQzvYk2o@a7zsl2Euuzco9RNph07T52Xg7nAqctWU3u28yjSsc@h0M8R059ESl9gf6ZeleFzmN4wQv@F6Tgu@heLb797DUHdbquFvCZ/c3338t01RZ9/OfaLNkm0LzuNhLJvPnzzodNY81YbJc5qCUKtzwb7S@9WX0XPybrKnpNl/UzImuqPtXO7dXkFQdAWbcwGw5A02QH@AG1MUhnFLMtuQiQVx6zD7llRbeo9mAMVDx9C0HASmOxgqh/HMbUpbRTeqKuejoECZdaJOwn7k2QIuLgagjusZib4iehjfdaAt/aYs3Gqv7W3mcUGFgOVnr8yLTHRkTRz58vFUjxBI2klOyvP3imKR0VrIBF3PWdVWytaiUpZYqbZypL7y9xfenmBHHlKIaUqynryprefHaeVX0/JWHWJ/sqiZDuZVMaRSIyJBOzKzZ5cT44@g4TmsXnZmCoFgpDa7zn0xDB39mzdn5tOSuiEv2Y0rAxndnLczyfRgfP669IAE280JUsgEqZlZeGKrweTaCfKsj7oCZWPZLvE9HBlUeQ6nZIYVrDW3sOJaZGnNNdj51Q@YKfyKNjK@e4o0wKQT/INJc0MJgBLPjewYiBBGSzXM3e@rsgJuokn0SyYeoI/LsZCkBT@AHf5TYinznakxyg6Wa3LicoBKT5TVFr0UHpg1AY0J@I4xDbMkksXddE78JbSN9Y9SyfhHrEdIt6CPxp8yYmiIiSKFFLZHAl2I9gD@K2xZnv@iAtpZLM8TunxdF30@9O61FHbidnCVLDFlqy4pTVVVhA20Yp8Abp9PoC82Sw7ytJ8ul1mO8ANFzMXt491T@6l9mHQzxYiBy1Tf7/GvchMZMrtx8ZMmOL51GcnlbJjpj3fsgXdj/2NEihF7g48aAQc@/5K0q1q5J4qbYhz8gryhqKRU6yDrSHPtnU/4LOTM@ZOzrrQHZPhx/DAOszNnkyIwwRZjDJ8GR0BddOz3ZO4shFfYCbTnT5k3UVE9AUrEcaTskZR1bWFijgh9dYb4W5t4DDH97YLcDVDRZADez0hxngHQAejseIQczAeWSeIs7UD1QfTosDrQVG4qcVJUZCGRADTow24p7JUYRaLSs@mW7GvGMGJ3i18n9yJwLacZnGK0rMRy0CCD6djzVtOd5QbjfCqNw6GzFQ5SXQ@5IqAnnDOYCamg01obJmhsz4efYeeWQLns4BFD0TR0x1Zr9V1JhzhBW54OjgcD5cHp7nH8nqEzqQe6RQiJs8HUSlsRuAp3ipc0l/6yFCgC3JDYSFQ1jOaXeeRmwzGC4ZcFS43ZAeO1Ediy9oejDnia@vNEaYzKl2NtqskA/ONHuP6vocdVwsVkndZRkxcYFcr5JT1U2Nu1vksozYRGvMrGFnZSykgSsU9qELssSE0l7YnSK9Oo1rIjXztx4RJEf64zg7paZ7OAVr1tEBa9mPOM8i56p4oiECijdq3F4Y6Q2FWciYLazQpnZNkhag3ORQTQzMygVX1cUCWdQLaGF1ywGapbB3qcIB1a6kyLutLojDN0Y0GFeqaIw6cmmUjQ5q6PdyNikFPHfthf3fUNll9KjakHthHIUXhIVAv1YVseLGTjbKd4Z22o120KFByy3s2lZs@EroIJ9swtUxEcAAKwVh3jqRcWKURZXmymiZIj/U8HuCRkCp7RybLo3E2X@r9GeuyLEejqwSlJn5/PKlNV5bk5cTUYnyn9zGS1x0YNXvLoSPgoUMJSwrn@sBGP65ExBzQLrLXgr43O@IJw6E9EpIrcbLyNvtoGfRZpbZ7mLGJK0rR7EiyTiQFLWDQ2zOziIVxgQSkfJBL3KjCwGg@XaDC8Whsda3ANPugZqChnvYnXra0ONhzBxHZyAXXdz1PJnvGBuZ7a7g4ZZWWcALADIQIGXB1Oar2awXOksEkofV6afYFwdITE0tsnWdrGy4VZbdaSXwUblfhRKR0/mRqHiHntkjydQ4cND2QS04a6fXAzmxPLA/RuC62MoRL45CTzBL0mJ1aYu6Wh7llT7a1YrpyqFxa1sliFtgBFKK8AwGVJJxOucXGw2W1UGtbPp1Yt5cdkHoOadx4OtjmIDMcsQN@s9bSgOfH3IDVwmpRcVsKtE7rhUm4/mEHCFEUoOluHVA9GMtQiRic@oY3hotxL9zMNgySINJEXizmyD4wQoNS@QGpLAyFZWfz48zWZEFIhLm0AXgw2u52G4jfBBxjc1NxExPTMl0oCqVVMbvS4Cke6hVX96pFUSghMwPV3NKw@GRZiFgFHGRNGt2hAasohf5SyI7o4eQdnHIQb2WGTcYk2z/aZmmVJ5gdlCCUjerKJN2ERjdqPbZVY@E4c7G3x5Iy2ZB9Apgx9iKS9f5@wRyt@YSTR0VurU0dd8EMTrzNipUyyTi6Y4Pcl1KmBs3lsxNi0@szWbAb0PPUBWHa6AGGstAEiNsT2@XMjKt@vZCPgzhCacQWYCI@RnJB@9FknvXmymFO046kT/xm4WK/2xuuBPZM3VrZwRLYbeeyPxQKGfJW2wUlSBOQPmHp@GDE@7HGHDcnHoYtm3HKaVFjCWfQY3rOG8GsXoqSbTnkGl0F4@gEDCJqD7M2UpVVBIFHokcPHbsnLaN0IBkTyooFDYJqZZfzypaeo2N4Ba/DCkazRQXBthq5R3WpqqgJ9MpsnihrpByCk5xV155ojANoqYjTU3zkhmgmscu@PS@qY8Id3RTbGdy4HwiGizRhCUE6m1TyT71SBxS75vo9mtqhk0aDsixgKhXXLCNLnNqDuEUxCWqv8OUUDGtIBHdqTTB7eZ9BBsdtltNqmBLxLPMigCQNdKKkCZWJh/A47eeDvSwFeJ@RHZ2fqNBiY8@ZVX@9oyxCgKYHi1HWJGxwhGJAiBiHZd54JMPxAe4Im6kRWKlGFfyBGBYFaB7LIgeTHTWe04rj95HS0ECM1eODVsuzAHaXlOVkfBPabkdKEyFGcilFwGgnJdjcndjricwvfERgxVMO9RjF2OKOmiJ2ZJcilhOzqeVQhj0Y7nxvMJkeprBqH@AKCdLVChtNEICywV4emwEkr5JVdEI1i1V5elGZp364X9rWZIoOUlUkzfVcC4aNG3UPHJzIozG3M/VgD9lxxK9FGAZ2JDpUtuIBKc2VcNrE9SR1ZqwQYFt7GsXCVkYGqxRaUr3Rqu@Ju/6RJoU00K2NQ2@iEBxjsaGxEUcClFVaPVmBJMvFEKo@6ZpvQchO8X16Ap3I7ASxUVZ5tHNi9HGIKLtlPN4cfWgc1juht0UKC0QQwUiAVX4SiPFYAefHsTR1AmlqG5AWHr1s0iusWaWvSBakE3gDDk15X3OCkyhDiNJ1GlljmILnB1M4ZqslIA@4CUYNjnltD/1iWdOThCXXx1pa4bi/82qeXpMiUSNl7A97ycghoHibUVG9mTijnjW0F3a2OOlGCJCnYjkd0UOQsDRVUHewPYQOazPI9469mW@xNQkZxIQXqt1uwEIhZXvDaTBufGKlLerj2lN9fcVnmAvEvApOyRN5Wu9WSzMSlNlir1cORQnpRPaY4qQmoiuCyUma6vF4IITB4LRtFI4UGcKTgqGkuNuBCPNATips1cTgSI9zjw40JeC5HcGzOhwz21AhfdWX@6Wo1r5HrikiLqwTlSsHorAkSp2Fa8jQ1WoPomMgXp@O2@EKT7lllXC5EFtzmEa5nS@Fw0ICw/58pOd9BU50VOGqAuwTTVRAL2QGXepzrzf1x6tsskIZYDNyjwXtjckxKDTOpPAynpYDNCghBQrkqrT8ENaWA01Oa10acebSRGkoAV2qyufkYaYKOy1P8AgCsiNpVho4GTYRxMBViTUo5wkcNm8ReFti88jB0CzartdG3o8pX8IYCx@lchTLdezJqLsaU35luHMP6FknEw8kUTGX9akyGR83tXUpsaNtpGD9KNnXWYqQzByVtYMQphifJwInGb1oFWqaXYF10Bss0nUJmM6SNZXRobBLGedZnD1uTRgvdqWHRKftUEU9QWf3diUq@EmssJ45RiIxdJMwRSF4I0dDn66liTUHZqehddzTq54g49LcY3wscPy1AB993rWN3S4rkKnqcCvEnBJyb8X4EztjLUpi7JkH1Uud35F908JhANxPQwjtcwY2G27BfGYExME9Icv8xNjRcSm5@top2YQzPalY9iZQD0HLcc2H2ESEsELrhfRgnqppAFhDgq0lfkFm@x2by3gsoCWd7ATX2aKmsNeMECbpxgYvTH13lFixV3HqcrLO2Mg5WWBazaPxdDTqRcDEVpaH7KDFdsHiEs@pq8OKTZ0NoefZFKkPFnQ8RvysbxhHlZ1m/lKeraMpBYdmb0Gt9iYXSbHgYnPAYCh/S0HR2pgVsIULLD46yGPjMC1JMfaj3NgMd0i@FBtjNyUkPlGr8NTfw3aN4cNtxjtmsmtuq3cC0GIiqqZoe1FdibNcnmPhGvHlKvDJSEtAfMjwvIY42PkRRmzjKIyDuZNv18tynkLQ/kQWVjK25i7AoYnDTkVyhmrjsTpgJCQ8cBZKL/CCrVBeXIARYSWDqRMGcN8XPWvlNk8GhRS8GbxeupKzK/pb5rgGTqpuM9FMqeJ5368GfultpBprnlcbmcuytbjNzWmJ6jMq0Pm9uRmM@iujr2kZxUf9Ie8nhayH1QQnAG@Ebb0FNXMd0qem1lGdFwkjzE7T/n6Cg2o0o3NVy4MDH3iHpZ7n@oFy5fVqBik9yojgw5HKt3sFyoAJHQ7HuEWdpnuEkqKwLAqTF6N4ehRWi0bMFIptxjrEJspKyGVzYhnbidRE@rPYmq63s2Q93k7MwoyAAGvUtw@l8zGXjbYDf4dUU/Gouwjo8/OKJyjCZnSwJMLlvhgQhEKFs2U5GiQpWS8aq@8IR4GzxOUCQMKFOvTBmY0gdLo4ySUustaW1BeVXeHEgK2jPU1LcL2ajY0VrSfTKpRmiLOCqh3jZ6EmaSJrxDYP9A4JdhzU@RAmhnNysl1ZHlmZwwKdstVamZI5s7QVBT9UYuVbyxFib@qyQoURv8ojnKjl1c6fN6dAAIZTr4aUtcAtE3ZPu346ivVI0lgYmkFoJckrMHaiw9ICfQEdYQk5hGtBa17Gu14xM0ld8gJl3Jswe8DEjSG4ycjpjjxsDws33XogFTYmh7bFcrVoQhI9lzZ4vbIZFTnJfVrR9NEJGc4hFp9MCmaKojOO4VQgWxNhoy2HCt3OBgG6EuQNXoCD5aA29@udJParBb1TkVBQ1uXs/BjDILiyeU@UjstRLbkWOfTFod0DwOmqyngmscWBPEwhwbRHuOdPxqOxVcyNoh5GIOxMpWN5KEKLni0CzUqjkZjvWQNTaR@rjWnCHuYycJxowxnSp2U69V1j5i2lzMtKJbFdFj8QNZiLnuDOiYG42UaetF8uU6O/QKnMGvjrkNxJXq2X1tCcAXbOlEZQj5dkHvWOI3crLVYzcw0fDYGeLUdpDevQ6LCGyxyS6LWwcfRl6nJe4zhBVYpjOmhMSr6PV4CW7KdwJbNzk3ay/himuVnNS@4ShFdD0RugWZmC0D7k0cEpHs4wu6IccTUP4bRfmntwLlDQzuvF1RIgchNTtMxnRBtRVRlKhuIpyxa0pIPzVQBZIrqjepMTstGxxCz2Kq2G4/KgqouDLq8nzXFuQYtcLw6As5pPMspmDMSUen2OjcsEnqWhaOMhF6sSqtqgWg@m1QGdwyNvqiPL5f506hmzVInoQagv@trRk2gZwIY8bO4wK5lJg4M62hee0edqA9vGkwzc4su6GKc0RSI4U2oZJoehDNJs4IIUtj/u0d6wJAeQmYoKMOTBvhLHzS0Qd6S2hDLcXAZ5JlGb9ZAR@6P@hJsPtzbHrKfadguqq2l/yG7I2Xzv43MVyXpQb7H31ijgcX3fhPKcLty1O8qG43RQ73f@Kiz0iiq5TD1Fc61wnRCxtcRXuIgi2ZV8IHgYGy6g4e4URChF1AxgGrY5gwLR3yq0O5xAarBvHtCDRv/97aJIDTvN9ozS7Hxxiqi@xDtyOgn2QsNhoBeJYYeM6@8tbAeI0JoeUUowtw1eFUNK1d3tZoZRdlE371d1cJrbA6g5dUld7wt4Sw6b0BXHD1NlH67KpZyJxEDecAIOyAdxYCPTIcfJu9xEljzsjMpcoujJEDHCnr8cHnt6b1qNDEmZgB6IbkyjHMlsMJRNLauPO5iBU9b2ANIjFz17gOQVIdsp3p/teUwLpnHNz@gkFIUZ2psNV3bsp3Bvxf4IpHxkQpc4OjbLjuWp2ncAdtUfeKhsZ4YYgdX0uVtvFGj/Fw)) and [dobgui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxY54kggzxFVSjJvZGNtNWxEamc) (Windows/Wine, GUI, author me). 
dobelx64 is supposed to be the primary interpreter, and dobgui can be used to debug any issues with dobela.

Dobela code (with some formatting for clarity):

```
9        0        1
,,...,,. ,,..,,,, ,,..,,,.$^
.                           #
```

`'0' = 48 = 00110000 = ,,..,,,,`

We put appropriate bits in FIFO and then print it by hitting `^` from below.

`:` is generator of dots in dobela, and we need to switch all generators off as soon as possible. This is done by hitting `^` from left on line 8.

Another issue is dots moving vertically. The dots start to move right, but can be deflected with `#` or `|` or forked with `+`.
There are 3 reasons to destroy vertically moving dots as soon as possible:

- There are lots of generators (`:`) down the polyglot, if any of them is hit from above it will be switched on and start to emit dots.
  Program finishes when all dots are destroyed, so if any of generators is working the program will not finish.
  In dobgui number of active generators is displayed as a.gens in status line.
- There are lots of forks (`+`) in the polyglot, and when a dot hits them dots start to multiply uncontrollably.
- dobelx64 and dobgui are not fully compatible, and one of the incompatibilities is the handling of collisions of dots moving in perpendicular
  directions, see description of hello2 issues in dobgui.zip. If we want to use dobgui as debugger we need to stick to compatible behavior.

So if we have `.` or `,` followed by `#` or `|` or `+` later on the line we need to destroy the dots.
The best way to destroy a dot is to use `_`, which destroys colliding dot without producing any side effects (`_` is input command in dobela).
For example, on line 72 we have

```
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
```

which becomes

```
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
```

If it is hard to destroy a dot before wall or fork then the dot is destroyed after it deflected/forked.
Example of this is INTERCAL code on line 12, first three commas are destroyed on line 13 after they are deflected.
I don't destroy them on Incident/COW line because Cubix code is constantly moving along that line, and it would be hard to maintain.

Another important incompatibility between dobelx64 and dobgui is how switching all generators works.
In dobgui it is handled in reading order (lrtb order): if we have this code `:$.^` then during the first cycle generator emits a dot, this dot
is put in FIFO, then the generator is switched off. But in dobelx64 the generator  will be switched off immediately and will not emit a dot.
For the polyglot it means only one thing: all generators that come before `.^` on line 8 will appear to emit one dot in dobgui before they are switched off.
I replaced `:` with `=` after `coding`, so there are currently only two such generators (see line 4). First of them emits dots on top of another one,
so they are destroyed immediately. The second generator emits a dot (in dobgui, not in dobelx64) which does no harm, so it is not a problem.

Dots moving right that does not hit any walls or commands are not a problem, they all eventually just fall of the right edge of the program.
That's why it takes so many cycles to finish in dobgui - the longest line is currently 554 chars long.

To summarize, if a dot hits `#`, `|`, `+`, `^`, `$` or `v` from left there is a (potential) problem (aside from situations where we deliberately hit `^`,`$` or `#` as 
described above). If a dot hits `=`, `:` or `_` from left, it is not a problem.
I added `_`s on lines 8 (last `_` is for commas from line 2), 12 (to destroy last comma), 13 (to destroy first 3 commas on line 12), 14 (to destroy dots from line 15), 17, 22, 72, 77 (to destroy a dot from line 78) (`x` is for Incident).

A lot of languages broke, Chance's [Lily answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113164) helped me to fix them.

Comment: So glad that write up was useful! I've been thinking we need to do another write up like that, but I think it would take a team of scientists now. :P

Comment: Oh cool, you got the DOBELA interpreter working. I might have to look at it again.

Answer (score 7):

## 110. Ruby 1.9.3, 3545 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[       _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                           _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1k4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"arY\"[2]==89and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                x_
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002663 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3642 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIkthzI/wP9qUEchoACYAEKUr8ljTd6t2e6R7Jre6Z2SbZahAERbRAgAOAEtVqdqxf7nbWF/Z5b72xN3feud2wIzbCfjqHI85xG@EI3@v9ivkDnn8wzqzCF78k9Z7NFoFCVVZmVmZWVtYH0X3dH/3wQwY/5Ni1r85sNyCB6Qdk4FkXpqeSj6/Ivm75lVKZ4yiU5w6mhuWckWBkEsuZTAMytGzT5ww9IG0yCbGomCAZ4pn6gIFxQ9cjWIWMz21iEWMyIX1bH6kGsS2AfVSsEnPsvrHIWyjPEN8dI3RgehPPhKtPHNMcEH9iGtbQMihVYs4C0/Et1/FVYhnn5NKybTIwbaiQsGLIgIxM/VQWI6xyA5cj8DEmS4zHT1kTYBwzarw50T3aeJdMqCQiGVx6@mQCTHIZcgKMB9bY9IkVCD4xdd9CiUIV33QGVG6TWNYu0Z10K8mFpRMd@J16FLdvegE0T6V4ycj0TECpI/EzTx8T8dKzAhABivWAHJu6R557pikBFVCH6Rv6BPhYIAnEXKQQYENUqrZmUzg8eiSA@lgNVZ8EXMYrP//Xn3A6UVske9qAb4vnG9zhZw/JdbaLaeACkIGKJ56oS6T1nviFbteE70zrF868OQdYOZCKTQruJCjoygQYVAJgsKBjElPKRUmd2CnCpLmki5RRMagBaIM8dsjnMm2ZMfU8E/hIhKqfQ6Nt1zkDeUJjvamD8nDIThFUYLjOwJeJeQFScx2mI/eSSvj5yAKl@agSvQ8C0g2UPesQVKDQJcD2QolGdH3XnlI4qOkHaIAgFaiKGB8PyedkqFs2VoFyRMW49kx/agdYZ@oMUPNjyzEHKonYMNwBAo3dCyCnA1KaAX1onOp5lCkABkW4tKlY9N1f/s3g7AzwHBiG6w1Cc/2cDFxjOgaGdcqsDqaIBus6uk3ZAjgZqbPqQOBCt62BHiB55yokQZmgVC/dqT0gLhD0Li3oWiP9ArrjcGgagcmM3J0GwKNMxvo58xcWs1xo@Fjvg2IpAUqbNlsh@w9AS4bJTEYZT4NhlSiTQyL4hVfiXl3c2@qawJukSrlsoXDWAHtTczQLnoSbDOfzg0SfaD3PLRf7kT0ZTcFrQInjT8CfeChMQ4fm@OhWAvCBMulTQVNfBKZOO@mlKXgm6UPPjhpGbYTZANZXsOeGGBKdRnCLJmYOUhYG1glGFvgrbsJ2L4Ew5Q0dKdi0g8T1Mx1IBWGDDliDGEWas9i0cwcsHbH1TVJV@hZoB@0AnE2ojFQbAbxcYjCAjWkv1SnG@hVgMZiTTjRJrCEoeQx2610Rw8TOAL3CZJ4OiUypYfgW2JE7JEWlVKncovzAKxwoL8F7vC3cqGNs/JKaD8jQvCS27pxN9TMwZNeBKrphmJMg7EHQEj@APrLsCGmmEnp11R9x2f1l2tS7hf4@RQO9D9Ne6KN1NHsQ1BhErdjQy4nundGeSAaWB/3FvlqmDgAXS8T51wiywMBrfgML0dAERmbOTGMaQHcDQ74cWcYIbBe5c1iHZd5xmTxkpamDy1GGMWlkRmvfL3FqIc5CNjaiUFCjq3jA6yOq9kIGVX4642bMuj9eg9iNWQQPlcpVC7oKthcKDcbzE4wlwP1FgzftWXGAEcsTBAxdHbopGMsoCCZ@HdyNFYymfRXUWnjuXT0OjhzUbCHwrqzAZem@7fYLY92HzlSIKBSMad@aLbWI5sUCf@NzFzCMD33SAv//1RRMRBSGviA1aP4DBE4V8XRopSjYlQdACqSCpMShr2II9gg8wMmVY4i8Su1ehR7Cy4THXsZLkMBasVweuGN0GeQLOrxgvPCxB25mCK6Fm1wFI5CDYhBeb7kT0xGFBaMUJEpQlBo0OhAE9Y1rOeK1sLW1JdSFtiBDag9STUztYSoPqT2aUmgK4VRM0RoyTWFph9bAvJ4w70SYZ1IP1TbDEOitNRH1Tr1e7sl6RwvvJbxL4JfADQG0gjfAI0itFiYliW9fQkPV/pC1/hmT7IBawzPTOePM2cT1AvLZ0cPD0@OD5z9p8YWp7xVsq19wYEA8HUN3gxCYX1MfYtmoOiSfuW7QogrDfAr9OB3hDj13HHsHnzONkUv4bJnHyAxDYwUdyhjjtslVVLqNpVPH1sf9gY75FO1zcEBPIAIiTywcmIYLdLhYYF2OZwotL7oWPikpseDtAkwZ3OTkav2gyqdR0QrA5rmLfShJnRZVrbKAAqYCqzWHlj@ilwXQFbZWS2htf9wf0ssagHo4KsIQi5MGlMsnGHLiwOy6MMG4pGBj13EZKyAvy9ELz@hNBWe6jp9Fn7XATN8cTiEMLfQtB9O3gCm1KoUc9vvWJlCQC7Ie3deAedP@OrGBCxutDGtkQfDB1AtscxDe//lnA1DAqnpG@pUP8e15nDgFuaGqlOFGbYVV8YFe1mv2zdSG2c8tOAwdY1rdjhPrcWHHJIoy0j3Q5lWkTbBGvICTvc3eoavY04EZ3dcToTJdHC1ZbccaU03CHYd@6k03VF8a61l9nBN4tqsPKBY2V7PMRL1MEeZMP4PGFVLzR9Xr34HPaEgmyeQMhrNgyq44H7tNkdYEvzd10BCyWNH7mllwfb1vbZAiMrGzyZBZ/8DhRxna@jlLnmJyfVNZYzzrDCZ/0X0TGAREELNOdMMsXNLbRp/iTP0JUwWmbsDn2ey6CcRyDAh9nSSxCRCaadPLh5gdNQQD@gayiushSkpE1pJQbb1/hUP06MPtBwme5fNEAX/SMvL5YpkobjJdSVZeJpPN9Q0jrF@rra/NFmkoAsOFmaV5W5@FgcYa67ZSGqSSG31uFNIkqXUuSb/QIdixdR8MJAjFbF6AWujlJqPFscOY2rqXpG4w2YSdaFa6aWKT1JlYhmtboWVGD5t84XKUmaDB5Td6Sari06p8BxDY4bisxKn1Hdo1ApxcbLCjO7gnFtfjzCllGKq7SXaGe4nfjb135F6Y7Lp@jHq7lqs7uB/FppYBk4XV6gPjNnPFdRN6WS/F87VcBYa9Nr9OnrquBxM7n5TUIkY0Dl3sgxHattnc5fnjo8027Vu265MTer1JFhCB@j67rrfmtNgs3VGMEetjcXp9tbVM0eGNHNDrBuXq9plr71TPCjpcNlrA1Builw/vd/VwsYfStFs9VBzfuI4W3je69nP4u804cMEAfLmFgU6cXG8oG91ZOK3Z3ECYB@AC0frGPSpWY8vyfPNGk2Kq8IzRpX4V3f@EcWSTnKNxZHJF42SI67BCrQqJwGOx859CbftmaoO7easVtLu3NSKl5nPbBN9NryvKJaWi9oE1tGLx7r5raE/NqbnWlxz135hgQDep/O5MFcNmZMMZcAGEh3s8MdTbcBZ4J65xZMenG12PblvQ3W@Na9Y6nQnE2hOcOh9D4hgTqxXPnOlkQbkp2T2bOs9ultxoEvVxd7DAJJZ8qG@q3h49LQTkvkm/611JnRyOXZjrumOIJpw76D9ESlcn2HUBMc1JML@xHkAo4t2It07iFS2IZCEyAa1a574Coc/GMWDR8ZQ2TdIpcK0GszLHDK7wukna61xq33XtD9EOeNaBhQEbhKG42Xmblurk5GrchxjOSJbb7qCBaMII0sLJ8UbFHgPK4I44y6vLTTeMV6nFp7WUf@za7Wb7FqU/w76rqVV19xbAh0cfHz45uBu2mlq@CTBcr6Pbg/F6vS@H@5qQZ3nhLpYfbxVnHjuGZ9LV@2iBmGRwT2E6hgg/cD2VUDhR1PN5SeJYJQwSzxwAi6DoZh3ul7B9QJ9A6B5QWGtIOh2SvZ7Vi3VtTlqEr/Ok12NY6cr94WxCd9mesaqdrN5rZQVFEbJC16mTokBBTRvG7LWg@gLc0KI3xmfSdOLoY7pFg@mopQ22DwShNG7@jXRnYJvkBZgenWC4HtvNYFtmz3ER6Z/@MAj3RM9MaOTY8sEznzm4j@@OzZF7ucfohtQPJhMd91QRB0yjbbaRojw4IP6lFRgjthUKkf6LR8@r4T5WeMIAHo6xj6e4YEpFqwce9IApjXEzcE1mFiHhuFbUKJhLTccOubQGwchXIS52DJPuk8Wrs5BCMCfwXDQrmTwmAxPn9ANk7M0UdGu77jldBUZO/ukPbPcOCi00IUxH5Ol2cooiQeulW2aG4U6B6wjJW9NzQxARhQwzwik6STBqk@VLxBjpdFsRLFGJNtWQDNtYe3BwQpRDIuBxCFz9b1hDMXvw7Mefd4q91nsyLpj//LOCdB3Kjf9I2dV8XiYRSGOOdpUuLkJxUioQPjvjw2bhxjvdZ46NivUmImKaqivaJBvTPXtqd@Yl3SSjO6EO@k/cDHd86B/wKFHUrNO0suLUtsZWQJSTgFTwzIgJIoEU2@UneAoDN3ywSnZG3pER2opiEK1ShCcmEBv3GMetj6Ml2HJ6qbzw0OxP6RLSRUktlVu0OdnTFrgzTHnmwMVd6M6r7mWv4EdS6XZnHxVLMxCb6wH4/QL2nMPPHl5n1Xbx3TsfYmOenwsNtoIP3Tt7ffz4@PDk@cHzFycgxjlrZeaR6431xEWgEUxsmL@MXJtu64M8PMv0b3cb96jf4O6FgKJIsjppQrRIwEPdix1LKFZe4bMsycqoJ4nLlgpD9zG0SOjqyDHVdqhYwU@7OTkyABQe9Mkp@NWIeTCc6zXuijaHJy1okAINouAxw/HTuoYtllJ4JvA9fAahh81IQ9GmJlDrgbCtDDjkm8EwJtc2Yv7/iPMJjCO3c45Qt3EOwNxt1FOEHx08fvLi2eEq7RTZEGYFJLaQ1EmqwxlER@AHh9TCcbc@shs3PG0ROQbw@yO2J6vbiWvzyYXlW33bpJY0RMdsQ9/GTkEXcn3s3AT9iEoObB8c6WAAnqF/FaBjAY@q0u0ztoemOITPgADUeJyTCc8hrN9a3XUHx3EJ0Z3xmlXOUjiK2V93cKVrFr77y79hh1W6AaS/DtNDSP8FS78qoIBWTzcwHmPRoFg@f3xMfBitWMPH@izVJhwwcECyHJjVWWOQ4AUVCIIzZpP2JnjEzucgT1ACCBM9Hzo7Ss/0eiJud9cLBRzfz1x7qNL9HnMGegBfSXe/v5ri2SHwz4Wdys62VgAmlYsIoWIxhMqEIZSkOpgQd2FNWq/7Bmk2m4T3Ico3WzsNJshCVn9V5l/HjGYBlmOhQIdAHaiS1ICydlhNzOp5TcKq2AsFTSC9BozyTC8wUIg0ASASZjuhPHgYidxQVKB0x5wF1KleRSEOxBeOS8YoJ3qCLEKkACKGW@K5FdtN9hVwjzVlzWpaDfwXCHaCYHV@nel0XpFu0HV64VEnAgbzd2sMyYH0L9acf4qt52D1mJO4fEgJW0P2TxwXd5oeAbdELBVK5YK2I6V6Ch@iAn6xX7wDlNAToGcZpvXGnfgHDw4ff3J0fLJyTIdCCstgAhHazXxXUeVOL04IS1YfCfXjR4WTpx8/ikSZ5iqZqCFEMltbZnMdtWVON1D/gm3qrNKmBSuEtOJdEdOpnvKILmisYk9KCynAB2zReYWqKF3PO71mu@tkVsi/W3eoLqPm0Lgg1fXpkTqBrPE5j6OtqufuOdiLGp08KPHJiVGDo3NeN3xOsjcf3gkQm/U2fcYo2hTDAzyldmFgXhScqW1zarJdxmfF5kLLJB4koBYYQXqGhbEXcQ0eJ2JYQ4YTsga3svGQ5omELYpJp2vGOkJRHbE5Ij1PqDswPfBgDk@hfeqm2UySHn6DucTjIJl@wJQGJ@R0lnVFZxTgMOKF/IFFN3x0LzrsEZecmGNLeR7xg@4jOZYD7gyPm4ygbbbVb@itzozEBz5uOrGj@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@JPwwAYwmllwx4fCte1CVJMtNOjksjGH0f91F4f/YRgAXBV@VFALjWsxa7euChCSSW0xO2pp@XIun886OTHrYFBy/z7OSedZiHlOVV7lZwCkZG2pAfYMMVIr6zSyelPMDlqlHK0Bj/m8dA0V3vsF9TqrzwvZ@xBTyJDjsd4pZn0Ju0NRVbU58Ic9JFuQwWauRZ7wMzwXjOSzVj6PPKjZU2TgfaF7kqejS/ekQGfBjTDULZyNIzeyoJYffshoOzDr2tspi@5eqbyVy5DMPl/IdR@@fPngoiF09GFJ/ap3fH58/KXUFYXMgyNe2@YbJFfgMoVc8d1uofD69WsIAkmnrbbVntRRhF5HbO/u5hryTjUn78uaIDcyxNaKmiaJpZJ00t3V9Vx@u7TvNCzLmviDAXzdEcS8EAq1UEH34CNqx4JQKQsnr/Cs4t4W/KN/8Ikf8bpFc8JsCrL62ZKI@NWMy7TvgVGVd7b27wHDZp5@6vV9Ohngd6u86@5zmfdc5orLvG6@5jIQ/Gba7d58nlc66qu8qp728kq@2Wk21XZ71lZ67U445zolXOaay8zmXKbEowBzXKY1az6jJDoP24xW/isAfQL3ptLrTI6fHB6cHMqlppIpPTp4IJdOXnyc0eCpkjxiYRkfnx0ePDx68VwusVo/fvz54YtjyPd7p@39/byqKMq@2u51gIeP8u18KwgC8vI0p5LNn9M1KfbIZR62Zy8KShNYfRLmPKM0lC48dSWg9I7LdDIdca@0VyraxYuidq6dbx/tHO0/dY@Sv6MjKLRmxTeuVxwVR9pA07RZ0XxRvCpezYpj90gbQNKEf8UxJK3icFY8KzpFR9MW8Gz@Gx@5T49cQOVCtWBWDBBrcQj3s6Ojp4BsCITfwD@rWEQmZ8UL@CvaGv28Oi0SIhW7Xa5D@Ncm2LKqCWpRUHcEwepVdiZfXc9LO1916FBTqfU65swKejyRhdNup1arCb1GpuB3uwXWv/gSdA4Emc9PTx8ePD84PS3g/HvWzOb388o@fFrtfDO87WUGbZSq2tzqcoJ4@cUXX@D3i8uLS5aiCZb3RVyYfqAJ@FxsqLuY2GAHotip9K7nkiTd6woNgbVEFE2In0Re685KQ1LiaVhSA6eklXHo26lI7fZOBZ53qpIiFrGUVejyk8mky6t0sqbSrb5W68Dz9CsMzcRtCfxil9e9n3b5TqnXalVrWLes1LaJ6ym1ssRL0iut2QxJlCTI5oUZ73oCuZ6n/4nX86ZIPxL@kyTMDK9tSYRiqQJPs2tx1hSbIuZBFta6nrcxSeGuIdURpZ40n7M8uIpSk@FsSyA4nJH@f/pzfeJPiJCZZ3Boc8h2RYL5rilt74jVfC3819qCxoh8WShDG3lBFzqd/Vw5t7vd2evlejmxmVNz3XZvlv5IQoaAUUdG2NIyKEMuozae8VqJF9AoG7jK69qmasPss1xrLFqFcCrmlj9VrZbP5fc7uVqN0c7l3m1B/wF0QIyHTwYMmYik2W7G1pWglNrwvSahwCE9vwaDY2UwUorhcm63OysWKXyj38peZ/R5g6Inc15oLNgtRS8KDbrOz1/zWd3raD1@zmev@3OMKHKaRCOBynajkdtm6d1qA8YvLReWFKEkTEKB6esG7cAwZKFlCSByCRrV6ptnlgNRxIKM8pVKpVCC6@yjncPSjGvgejhbfOcVnnUkUq1RhBni@zUOgtY@KP6S7BZhUmLbukfc4XCL5UP0TfqmCQGQadu4koTBKcRo9uASJkRbXAYcDoRmUAyf8bFuTk3zcjq9NOPPA8uv62/ewNyKfr7/9jd/Bt8/wPeX7P7L/1ar4PX7b//Df/nut7@DzH@E7/@E7z98/@1f/4x96fMf4fu/Unl/DL8pOPblANe//f7bX/3@@2//4hv4/qfw@83y97tf/z37@9/hP0z@7rtf/xEv7AFw/eYX3/31z4HFX2P6zyENf2H212EylcuSX0dJqPe3S8C/@P7bv/p9mP55GiSVD1W/hvzfpvK/5jhU5hap7MqyqqpwwbtMP/SuZl9FINrmYTbDPcXFrJrGtvYsrAEpz6xxPwEzGE@NEe6YWgFGVDDVKXIqGk2pVKtWqrVyqSpXa9XtirZTqchaSdZ2q7u1ogzBVFXbqVZqmlzdrpW3t7drMtFKldouhL7OwBoWChCAaDxPaAJm1Himuomn0V111OYyA3MI84l7ZCYOpHuZQZRBplXCl6vdIszh6ZRHJBK5xsFPJD7MfIFzsShPweVX9qZVfmeXr@fgzu/xZUjSBs9EUhSg@/JCl@elTq23x@9W@DoEcYpwX9sj/G4N5kK7u7zU4Cs8v0NKuzz/EqzdPFMEMtvjG3PgORJG3BoCw6SqEvgqCoflkxZjSORrIqH9otblmddgXVAQBWG3JAiS0AAkW3xaK1IDWweNY22LmONBrsBcDYa7hmcGU88Rawq4YKLUpMacsfSvUjx55zDz0j2c/VCSdcLv1HjMBpCmWENS7Uo/V5c1Rd7nmD/Y0bjMnBvgydHtGmnUGhg5wpjVbHNZAdkSylxGKbvbbiabzUIQ@rzNl/kj9bRZCKPIdoGGkF2MKjEoU6NIFfxrgfNM3Kga4A@G2UherWBrzoifyf@JHxVItAAn10AXz2cmbJC5wpiZdBlLzfcZOtiT4@toH2Lq0OWU@lOUtV4/oafqOz0ivf/Msq@rZaVNp4EiyJaAdOcntVe7r6qvnr44enH0aL9Yr9ar3e5yh5pBLOq/k9yK9t75pJGpT4TytlCGoLSVYc3VdqVMu7Sr@vpVphdusIvbuxKBJ@rnS1pmiEFTElutxFSp1Jrny4sxDeiBkeqPBmdnVulHT1@/yxYKgkCIlt15rzTZXxMuD46Y2kV@p8JLeDDBf3X66jQD3pzwpQqaZb5AQoedHt1mOYf@M3M@/WeaSYYPj9ETlptSDqaoX5bAbdRqO9WdDPdDoXDTiiKUxpProQmTzul43ez6wLOe6rjy4MQzbEg8nb41vdirEHQruGiEfiWdF7qaVBb9BTzkccgX7YGY0L0zQ6ZbTSSHP87o9MDnRNuUIpbiTpkUb6yxnkmKDbYBiiisRpwEKugYSAsBqBlCkCpaLa1BrCYigztMwEMK@Ilq5FuYxIU3yoXVkxpceseQctKG2ileUvXzeQY@Z2yx9hjjAWs2K4sfgb0xnqwwxLC2tATQKfZwQadbFMJm3qUZhh6IMQaZfHAzlurzhJeiNlEWksIwP1HFnMsF8rjBYbNzkwb3qWhI17gG0ng/vn/feDXpjHsNadwK8J7Pj8GdnosWA8kFrXFL0RoTYLYRdPJ5q9caS5@KE8r8uFUEYKCNmH3pOta00wrV5Uvy246jvHd68qOOk9d68lTOvWy9lfVWUZ7BF8Qm2/JXILxIlGLQept3GnoTvrgcsyAJGFryemNxIxeqnIt2621H77WKUsOGivn8I2gM8Ol37Hy@JwFxGwpXKzbs@/f1vN2eNWxFkRDqVXnvUSeARC/fwue6qDdne287U6hfF@HeAjK2BMxDvUUdAD7grwEyZupLWGc8zpC9GbA3brVyL/dyL3Otra23nZky7slM/PVionhkfobMp21EzL1MGxYVCQ3NRf4jq/6RmvMJL4P1gZDlSaom4zD3EkomSW@YoyuiP8ePlvpwATjcwWW/wKS/kqMr9/h6DTyX4mIeHiWBuge@YVkhODsDNLHMAf5YwfJlCKYdRacQWBa@sAILu7O9PS4iHW4vAmU8vNM3iY4neOivwz2cKNCXn/iGZ@GLOG52Yut8XezYojjq5PHLQwIxW3kn5ewk7pq7R/2C7xkdBME@fl2cN7h7CMQ2lVsgE1whBxiI6WSKSoE7FZKEoNAXGGQrLMQYLVQQ1CL96XDIDn3ijyx9dDTQkaPOqkFvCtmAzryGDUt@g1Z8D@3JghQ4HEqPeRzuHjQCecA2WD3SBkdL7t8n4WOzBXHoLkBRMIR7k9cQaIVTIH4HTgEHcvkGbBSYZESAt3tYgmchFght/8sIheeJRKiQfyOzY0Vq6UtexiV1nx2jQ7lJjA3Uxb17b/Kt7ZAh@KPhJNSHsvkPmXAkrZMHR0@PXzw/fPb04ASuWmm7ymXwPI7vWoN6/K6KlR@9T/DH7H3LoRv/hv5MM3/6iQGhAcRZYFLuAN@NMiCfvHgC84XPHsp4fh1Ej8eywMBt363HmEyf/iDYV13vrHBpnVuFw4UDp1CJnTHw6/TlEPQnEA6@KgPnoPg6lPhwX3K2z8eZjD6IDt0uvFZnbPp@@Ft@JXq7Dn2DED3mOMbTetALw9/@042b6JUNdKcD58gy3T/zrDOLvjJlxBAs1Ke/rQ9Yddo/OPzN/kAPdLRorlYtFuukKGNCixKlKFGOEttRohIldqLEbpSoRolamNAizBrDrJWq5fJOktxNktUkWYuT28UkmWDYLiXJcpLcTpKVJJlQ246p7VQpXpKJpEm7LoRrUKZtV6MyPJzrBDSzAmi05cxtYLS0AgnVt1cygV51MRNmqCGhx4UjBCqVdpJn8D4RbEtkXMmMD5lRZk9hJoxVHJtXUIM99DzwSoczfKMIGJ1UJ3j4iuPA7RLDNnUIBswAopTWI7B/U6qzQ7zeVT0epEzE0NLiZ6huwgwO6mhoRaH5rCkurStm2EprsbFT0CQWTCoIC5lkXNYXz5VRjNsLeWmsW@hgUaIbIEoMAnWQcGmnaD73pmtJlm8muYBwLckVphjeyrpaKBuRIm9FVen4T7G1InosTjGptiEMCN/NRW1gSaF4mrt1rdX577/95r@S77/91e/Id7/93f/5h3@P6b/Hy3@HmIWUYoBf/govf4uX/4iX3@Ll16lKFL5c57/75u/g8d/9Z/Ldn/2KFf3V73l5O0YEJZiV1PzNn@Pl53j5H7xciQF/8wsGiFV4ec4thFYiQP3yHwkBaoglRvbNHwjh8xBgiKHldVgf70nSEoJYDB2a6i2Xs6sx8lDsRSkPwX0@fNKSpzwqQEoh93R82VTS9yCcYccd0EsbujHCA4Zhlutj/GNgCOP66hnY2@UAgp5wXi5A6/8NqRMhjzCQTQ@xt5gPD9sftptPShE2zxeAO3iOUGFaijnxr3wO7JvOBK58FWc9ErUhZiOhfD/Dl9lFAwgfWZYViDANCmlFtTtaj4RvYIK/qI5MjRaHIXYInL6biwvPymkpggvuZkltQGU5J08SZ7RQlWaY4wmoBKrF8kbB4gOVgryMLtFc2G0Ojx4tdRj89CHEPE97pJhQi/D8LbAo6RBewoirvAjP@A0BOsV6ucelD82uA@a//PJLnkvlFdGGvIFIMaQaxVxGXKQtFpVSRaVUEfDMcFJfUymVlnigAwf6RWn5mPCii1qslhgX9pxID8gGzAXZCpw8tKf@qLWKmnrkRWe3ijyFUuu1wn7SdajPaRNeWqkAOBfrtJZ1uR51cQVmVVHra6K0F3IWtLUZ00KdVKeg0uOWpRRrTqut09wiwRtQa738HQmViv9CQsodCe1Ubie0rFasu4B@s3xvdzuRm4g9fIKMdfzMwgCFQ@M3YHqJO0KOPZoUJZjyHIRTnv6lS8Q1b@@C/EL0A7aFV3Z5qZ@14STmMzcw2fLA/sSFKYeLUXDqjZEvQvCFaQd7QeOZ43qmnz69brEzgI6Av4ww3DMHRjUZf0hnhS@Pw9/zsB@qLY4r8cgWRqEP2EsoETUTFEaep6eWYwWnpxB82kMpESA@qgau4wkcvr0SUqn6YhzaHk1EF38AHEi346TxLqv23DLOxaNJWCgAkQMCEzrDtGHyRUa6cY7vYaUiwSbSs@QYkfYDUUIhjtyxe2Y6Lv4qBGsvoX@c4EaG9MmE8iITXSZGiqNwEi0asi6FVT/94Krk05KoS3H90iKCBWHIxFuWMUrWW0PudCM5Vi2id/Lh/J6k@T25md@h5fnBMs80E1d78P5hpMtiggEAEzbKt7Mhhz/WWmFngZU4G9@KxyrcmcWB6Rsw/CGnBwB6EIKrQ7APOX7y4Slm/PNN8r9ZgVH1w7uqjwazJ1fgb8aHGPvRKZpPf6rqGKYI4I8l9D2r5GLTfnhHWuFEh87wZMJTx@Xg@T7omJOJ6fjxhmSE@Babt85GKzZEM9H28b6GJ@9CJuelzSp6eDowbf3KHIghpJzCG7X4makPqL@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@Chq8WgMKtFinlKDBOQBYGjdSIwejAsKHSt3CL64aPerQ0Fa5vJGsoUJ5vpRZV0Eqm1B8JGWHRGTHGsJQuPsJ9CzfdHaG@niOirczMbmMnpA4WSpVcX9pzB@mpNB4YiLS8A8DpRRw7qR/paxEFU@Dd@MTKm/hcYSciRznCUwPSGrZQqK@FGxqFul7kJdR@WkOrawSoRCUCYVqiaFM@HWI4jE0psYk7WTQSWoq7fVa6Dn7CTonWu1SNeoWwZ24optlhy9AxpDu/dFNzUvWQtQUXhIWdYo/1snhcoL4YixJfl4pUWecDFlI@Z0B/3Gai2T4MkxSOuRuZjhWbhqGoLiNJPdeim4TKKh7wnuoBo57sy@Cx7w@bvkY1IQQHHhFBqmZMhflX9wPid5fF71FAHQlhicC6wHr9ULoaXt84yi5xbidkVxWIhTJ5KK0NjmIKichhdpCKzG@ytZUQH99ty4J8RjTGvhTtR2KL5wS3yG15bsFwYZTgXSxmnuPC7Hlps6BWIxL7Qo2CFhUphXhYw2NOk6bdzCtr@DoVYwmO0XD7YAV7iwpOKw/x0QZ4SyJnvRzfFE/3KeK@HR07C3cu2K6Di6fY4hdIpDLB3dPfVoa7FTJmHJ0@e3j02ZOfwqC7u7srrW5FYK@Fusk4zt24TRBPW0oy/riX/vcneHZi5HrBVtfhV3wJc9YQDOh034aZX9jHpdCXpfz5Ut@Fegw2JdEQ13nSDfQFr4Shjo5DthXKNQCBmIGY00MkUXgL8pbpbA13jdA6cEPn9JQOX6eneDjn9DQcxVA18TbS/wU)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse (73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon(94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>  (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- DOBELA (109) [local](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/dobelx64/)

### Explanation

I once again dug around in [the ruby changelogs](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/) for a difference we could exploit.  Here we use the fact that:

> #lines, #chars, #codepoints, #bytes now returns an Array instead of an Enumerator [#6670].

So we add a `"".bytes.class==Array` to separate 1.9.3 and 2.4.1

#### Alphuck

Since we added 3 `s`s we need three new `p`s.  I just put these in the string we created.

```
"ppp".bytes.class==Array
```

#### Incident

`")` got tokenized so I added a space in between at the end of the `eval` code.  Then `93` got detokenized causing `49` to become *retokenized*, I changed the `2-93` to `3-94` to restore the `93` token.  `)o` also became tokenized from the addition of `or`s.  I tried to over-tokenize it by adding another `)o` but pyth started complaining, and I figured its best not to touch that.  So I under-tokenized it by adding a new space.  If you ever have a problem with this token again you should delete this space I added.  But I doubt even I will remember this, so its probably going to permanent.

Comment: It doesn't work in Ruby 1.8.7 for me. I used Ruby 1.8.7-p302 7z archive from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/.
It prints 13 in Ruby 1.8.7-p302. Answer 108 works as expected. Ruby 1.8.7-p374 behaves the same (works for 108, fails in 110).

Comment: @stasoid Thats strange.  It works for me using rvm.

Comment: Can you tell what ruby --version prints for 1.8.7 and 1.9.3? I need to know patch level.

Comment: @stasoid It looks like I posted the wrong version of the answer.  I have a working version.  I'll update soon.

Comment: @stasoid Ok I updated with my local version.  Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 7):

## 112. [Pyramid-Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 3671 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@   x/"78"oo@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#1111111B#_#xxxxxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[       _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>4O6O@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                           _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"1015""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                x_
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002612 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3768 bytes)

*Just squeaked in to make an improvement on the last one*

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** Pyramid-Scheme

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIktizEP4H@1ICOQ2ABEGCFCXxU63pVu/2zPRIbnXPzA3JZoMgKKIFAhwAlKhWa2L9cne7vrDPe@uNvbnzzu2GHbER9tM5HHGO2whH@F7vV8wf8PyDcWZV4YNfknrPpkSyUJWVmZWVlZVVlQAHRjD@4YcMvsiJ51ydOV5IQisIydC3LyxfIx9ekYeGHVTLFUFAqEP/bDax3DCoCxmiE9s17SFcktA7t1z7reVDdplMfe/MNyYkHBshsQLTmFoB8WbhdBYSb7S@VoUcTbw3dgErTmz3DKBCy5/6VkiLd8hL1zEmg6GxVFBdpDb1oTggjy3n3eRdSExvMjHcYSAw9k98bzgzEXs4tgARMjSyHSsQTKjbJlMuBA0TJEN8yxgyMGHk@QSrkMm5Q2xiTqdk4BhjzSSODbBPSvvEwgaQt1CeIYE3sdKcBsS1rCEJppZpj2yTUiXWPLTcwPbcQCO2eU4ubcchQ8uBCgkrpgrIyCxIZTHCmjD0BAIvc7rEeHyVtQDGtaLGW1PDp433UGggiUgGl74xnQKTIM9TYDy0J9BhdigFxDICGxUCqgSWO6Rym8aq4hHDTbeSXNgGMYDfmU9xB5YfQvM0ipeMLd8ClEbcY/Klb4cgAhTrITmxDJ@88C1LWVScBZJAzEMKITZEo93WbEpHx08k6D5WQzOmoZDxKy/@9UeCQbQWyfYb8G6JYkM4@vQxuc52Mc1UBbp46suGQlpfk6DY7VrwnuuD4pl/IwBWAaTikKI3DYtGYQoMFkJgsGhgElOFi7I2dVKESXOpL1JKxaCG0BvkqUs@U2nLzJnv41hIhGqcQ6Mdzz0DeUJj/ZmL8nDJbgm6wPRAm1ViXYDUPJf1kXdJJfxibEOnBdglxgAEZJgoezaeqUBhRIPucYlGdAPPmVE4qBmEqIAgFaiKGJ@OyGdkZNgOVoFyRMW49q1g5oRYZ@YOsedhyFpDjURsmN4QgSbeBZAzACnNgDE0SY08yhQAQ0d4tKlY9N1f/s3w7AzwHJqm5w@5un5Ghp5JLY9BmYUxTVBhPddwKFsApyJ1Vh0IXBiOPTRCJO9ecRKUCUr10ps5Q@IBQf/ShqE1Ni5gOI5GlhlaTMmZuVLJxDhn9sJmmgsNnxgD6FhKgNKmzS6Qh4@gl0yLqUxhMgtH@6QwPSJSUHwlH9Tlg@2uBbwpmpLLFotnDdA3LUez4Eq6TXE@O0z6E7Xnhe3hOHKm4xlYDShxgynYEx@FaRrQnADNSggmXCUDKmhqi0DV6SC9tCTfIgMY2VHDqI4wHcD6BRy5HEPSpxHcoopZw5SGgXaCkoXBiplwvEsgTHlDQwo67SJx48wAUiFv0CFrEKNIcxabdu6CpiO2gUX2CwMbegf1AIwN74xUGwG8UmYwgI31XmpQTIwrwGIyI530JLFH0MkT0Fv/ipgWDgYYFRazdEhkRhUjgOkLJ7JSoVyt3tH5oV88LHwJ1uNt8dY@xsYvdfMhGVmXxDHcs5lxhjOoC1UM07SmIR9B0JIghDGybAhpZoFbdS0YC9mHy7SpdeP2PkUDrQ/rPW6jDVR7Po0WHBjlxOA@ABnaPowX52qZOgBcLBEXXyPIAgOvxQ0sRFMTKJk1t8xZCMMNFPlybJtj0F3kzmUDllnHZfKQlaYOJqcwikkjM3r7QVnQinEWsrERRQF7dBUPWH1E1V7IoJ2fzrgdsxFM1iD2YhbBQqVytaKhge5xocF8foq@BJi/aPKmIyt2MGJ5goBhqMMwBWUZh@E0qIO5scPxbKBBtxZf@FdPw2MXe7YY@ld26LH0wPEGxYkRwGAqRhSK5mxgz5daRPNigb8JhAuYxkcBaYH9/2oGKiJLo0BSGjT/EQKnikQ6tVIU7FMEQAqkgaTkUaChC/YELMDplWvKokb1XoMRIqpExFEmKpDAWrFcHnkTNBnkczq9oL/woQ9mZgSmRZhehWOQQ8EkotHyppYrSwtKKSmUoKw0qHcgSdobz3bla2l7e1uqS21JhdQBpJqYOsBUHlIHNFWgKYTTMEVrqDSFpR1aA/N60k0nwjxXethtc3SB3tpT2ejU65WeanR0/l3GbwXsEpghgC7gF@CRlFYLk4oiti@hodpgxFr/nEl2SLXhueWeCdZ86vkh@fT48VH/5PDFT1picRb4RcceFF2YEPsTGG7gAotr6oMvG1WH5HPPC1u0wzCfQj9Ne7gj35vE1iEQLHPsETFbEdEzW/DttelVVLqDpTPu2mM@RfsEaHMXXgi9GYx78IrtiR0@pb644@KISXQhKn0EzWEIXoAF@wRcKPKJHdA1R5pRIZZ4VxCZRlQWbZOIJXXwOnDO88D1hflLTENTKUBTzj0cZ0mqX9L0KjQjQQfLhdWaIzsY048F0Jgygy2vKaG1g8lgRD/WMs1mTpiGcWGBTf8I3VLeENdi7Zh4rsdYAZHYrlF8Tr80MLjr@Fm0awvMDKzRDFzV4sB2MX0HWKG2TyFHg4G9CRTkgqxH32vA/NlgndjAzI1Xpj6yIPhw5oeONeTf//zTIXTAaveMjasAfODzONEHuWFXFUYbe4tXxQv6sb5nKcybmWMbVAw0dRdK00A32HDixHrUOJZJoTA2fOjcq6hzQTnxA@zyLXrGOPctZza0ou/1RKiIFydYVtu1J7RF8I3eAjXAG6ovuQesPi4jfMczhhQLW97ZVtLbrF@suXEGjSumlpyaP7gHn9EsTpL1HMyA4Yx94hLurn61p/i@bbxyyFLVGOhW0QuMgb1BisjE7ia9ZsMFZ6zCyDHOWbKPyfVNZY3x7TNYL0bfm8DAhwI3d2qYVvGSfm00Me4smLKuwNQt@HyHfW4CiTZ74sQmQGimQz/eR@2oIpgwNpBV3EIppERkLwnVMQZXOKuP319/kOBZPk8KYF5aZj5fqpCCl6xwks2a6XRzfdPk9Wu19bXZvg5FYHqwGLXuGrMw79gTwymUh6nkRhMceUFJag3oG@PCAP/IMQJQkJCL2bqAbqEftyktTiXmzDH8JHWLyibsRAvZTWuhpM7UNj3H5poZXWyyhcuOaYIGd@zoR1IVr1blOwRfEKfpQpxaP6A9M8T1yAY9uod5YksBXGylFEPzNsnO9C7xvXH0jr0Li32un7LeruXqHuan4FDNgPXFavWheZe64lYL/VgvxfO1XIWmsza/Tp55ng9rwYCUtRI6OC7dH4QJ23HYcufF0@PNOh3YjheQU/p5myzAaQ0C9rlem9Nisw23YI7ZGIvT66utZYpOb@SQfm7oXMM585zd/bOiAR8bNWDmj9DK8@/7WrjYQun6nRYqdnc8V@ffG037OfzfpRy4xwC23EZHJ07e4kWtM2d8JbS5geD5457S@sY9Ke3HmuUH1q0qxbrCN8eXxlX0/UfMI5vkHM0j0yvqNoNfhxVq@5AIfeZK/zHUdm6nNryftVpBu3dXI1LdfO5YYLvp50rnknJJf88aeql0f9s1cmbWzFprS44HbyxQoNu6/P5MlXgzsnzRXATh4bFQDPWWLwrvxTXO7Hh1q@kxHBuG@51@zVqjMwVfe4qL5RNInGBiteKZO5sudG5Kds9n7vPbJTeeRmPcGy4wiSXva5v27/aeFhzywKLv9aakjseOsPT1JuBNuPfof46UbmiwzwXENCfB/MbGPQn/Vrx1Em@CgScLngn0qn0eFHBjY9McsGh4ypvW7BS4VoNVmWuFV/i5SdrrTOrA85z36R2wrEMbHTZwQ/F89K5eqpPTq8kAfDgz2aG7Rw9EC0aQFi6ON3bsCaAM74mzsrpDdct8ldqvWkv5x57Tbrbv6PTnOHZ1bV/buwPw8fGHR58c3g9bTavcxxOaRu4t3TbDrTa2uZYc5GaW7Mv0CiRjDwuBObYmFr1ca2H4JiI9s4wPEQKVH7ZCnu3zo7UgPr/OPHVN36JHCtGuNcngQcdsAmuI0PM1QuFk2cjnFUVgldANPXMBLIKiJ4h4iMMOJwMCi4OQwtoj0umQ7PW8XqrrN6RFxLpIej2GlR4nHM2n9OjvOavayRq9VlYqFKSs1HXrpCRRUMsBr2AtqLEAN7LpF@MzaTpxjQk9N8J01NIGO5wCZx1PJMeGO3Qs8hKUmy5hPJ8dsbBzvBe4a/VPvx/yg9ozCxo5sQOw/WcuBhd4E2vsXR4wupz64XRq4EEv4oCFusNOdwqPDklwaYfQm/R8FtYSL5@82OeHazzsAS5O0IqkuGCdiuMKeDBC1mmMm6FnMcXjhONaUaNgtTabuOTSHobjQAPP2zUtengXbxlDCsHc0PdQcVXylAwt3DUYImNvZtC3jued061p5OSffs@OFKHQRhXCdESennGnKBIcH/QczzS9GXAdIXlr@R4HkVHIsOacoRmGYWOxfIWYY4OedYImFqKTPiTDTvseHZ6SwhGRMEYDjyQa9kjOHj7/8WedUq/1NZkUrX/@aVG55nITPyjs6YGokgikcYN6lS4uQXFSKhExOxd5szAagB5@x0rF42pkTNPuik7uJjSQgOqddUlP7ujxrIsWGk/o3QDGB1wqFDUbNK2sPGM2oXAakioGslggEkix0AOCoSF4CoVVsnPyjoxRVwom0asluGICcfDgc9L6MNrzraS334uPrcGMblJdlLVypUWbk@23wGBiyreGHh6Nd151L3vFIJJKtzv/oFSeg9g8H8AfFHHkHH36@DqrtUvv3gXgfYvijdRgxwowvLPXJ09Pjk5fHL54eQpivGGtzDzx/ImRmAhUgqkDK6Sx59BYA5CHb1vB3WZji9oNYYsDyjLJGqQJ/igBC7UVGxYuVrEgZlmSlVFLEpctFXLzMbIJN3XkhPY271gpSJs5NVIAFB6MyRnY1Yh5UJzrNeaKNkckLWhQARpEwWOG46t1DVsspfBM4Ad4DULnzUhD0aYmUOuBsK0MmPPNYBiTaxtx8/@I8ynMI3dzjlB3cQ7Awl3UU4SfHD795OXzo1XaKbIcZgUk1pBUeNfRHPwvsIMjquEYQhDpjcdDQCLDAHZ/zA6KDScxbQG5sAN74FhUk0ZomB0Y2zgo6FZxgIOboB3RyKETgCEdDsEyDK5CNCxgUTV6pscO9gouETMgAC2e51QiCggbtFZDAcBwXIL/aL5mlbMUjmIO1kXTdK3id3/5NyyCphtC@mc8PYL0X7D0qyIKaDXkgvEYiwbF8tnTExLAbMUaPjHmqTbhhIETku3CutGegAQvqEAQnDGbtDfBI3c@A3lCJ4Aw0fKhsaP0LL8n4xl8vVjE@f3Mc0YaPWCy5tAPYCvpkfxXMwxoAvtc3K3u7uhFYLJwESEs2AxhYcoQKkodVEi4sKet1wOTNJtNIgawjrBauw0myGLWeFURX8eMZgFWYK5Ah0AdqJLUgLI2ryZnjbyuYFUchZIukV4DZnnWLzBRyDQBIApmu1weIsxEHhcVdLprzUNqVK8iFwf8C9cjE5QTDWuLEBUAEcOtiMKK7iYnF3hum9JmLd0N4ucIdopgdXGd6nRekW7YdXs8/oqAwvzdGkVyIf3zNUFZsfYcrsZeycuRU9ga8vDU9fAs6wlwS@RysVwp6rtKaqSIHBXwi@PiHaCEkQAjy7TsN940OHx09PSj45PTldghCiktg0lEajfz3YKmdnpxQlrS@kioHz4pnj778EkkyjRXyVIQIZL14DKb66gtc7qB@ufs2GiVNi1YIaSX7ouYLiYLT@iWySr2pLSYAnzEtrVXqMrK9U2n12x33cwK@XfrIv0yWg6VC1LdgMb5SWSNzXkaHYa9wBDoQIvCIcpiEsZqCnRV7fHrJHtzRFEcUJ3EFUXHbhhVVG7Dku@i6M4cR9A2HMhB27UiI0VDahhjEb9gayJWdWQ1IWgKK4caaW4Ib8tq7DfUjHsHhXTMVoc0vNFwYWHg2yaDDqiBZmtIGosHq4inYbLwgMUMLvbp@uqKriXAVMSHBEObHiYZfhR7EpecWhO78CLiBw1HEiUEhgyjX8bQNsceNIxWZ07i8JHbAoi0YOrYoYyRO3MN12jQGlnBBuhNx8LAn2atx6OMSBQMlKfxRCczkNeJNyXJuvixFaWew9KIPJ4BclADi3w0mwDciH49t3CWsMinXgEqgxyliIkOUJF5G7TJsArUtbE1H9pnMNPIigom6QNdTyKRDCUP61kJ7DAT1Y/x9CMtmPeKnkpJzOgYmu0OrbksXUpKvYfSgXzp8vMLSRFXdICGcPF4ruFyLFdkLIyQj9okDmrJINRqsSFYHDu1mjYOhAlgBO8eKJ6G/ieQhDlUHk2MKZFnNBguIBqhl3JXdtUg9BVSaON8dklcks/TdQF80QKN0JojmrId3EuRMQJZLragnzE3cIf49daeko6uaT1IUyIKyeKS/hG4G7gYVgRwIqFKnaKFCRj@6sjRJayAkCP2naVkBVyP@wC1tpgO5LMxHYAgC9pq0n5AEmuQjEAm1Vqtzntj0RzWCKhFc43FALRrzFzkcYJ8eewGSA2NGEA9gpWeDQbl4ceW68J4lUFnJjA6iTEDJfMVNbrzRI2DazOUQoax@BMeDAKMZhYM8ZF07Xjgz2SLDbqsbNzAvP@6ixP/iE/9V8UfFbVi41rOOq2rIjhjSlvOjlt6vpLL57NuTs666I48eICr0ZsseDt9TdTEOQAVso7SAH0G76iVdRtZoylnh61yjtaAy3xeuYYKXwdF7Tpr3BSzD8CbUCHHZ6NTzgYKDoeSpuk3wB@OkGxRBZ25lkUizjFMGcln7XweedCyfWTg62L3NE/nle5pka5/G9zJLZ5NIjOy6KvEPbFyMwwTIM@uxxa9ihad7wn2I2CMyYv2PdeUrfOPfvgho@/CSu9gtyJ7B@XKdi5DMg/FYq77@MsvH100pI4xKmtf9U7OT06@ULqylHl0LOo7IjTmVYPkikKmmCu92ysWX79@Dc4n6bS1ttZTOgWp15Hbe3u5hrq7n1MfqrqkNjLE0Uu6rsjlslIk3VPS3TOMXH6n/NBt2LY9DYZDeHtj8LfBDWuhimzBS9ZPJKlakU5fYfDmwcE2/NF/eMWX@LlNc3g2BVl9bStE/mouZNpb8z/iVdT1chdXa5Xd7Ydb0F4rT1/1@kOQyLwo7u2LnvdwQ@0CvoTM10LmbUbX9cwV/Ons9WGmn4nhhMzr5mshA85@pt3u3dzkCx3tVV7T@r18Id/sNJtauz1vF3rtDl9j9omQuRYy8xshUxax83JCpjVvPqe8dR63GZP5rwD0E/huFnqd6cknR4enR2q5WciUnxw@UsunLz/M6HBVTS6xsIKXz48OHx@/fKGWWa0fP/3s6OUJ5Ae9fnvnePf44cO8Bm17qLV7HeDjg3w73wrDkHzZz2lk86u/JsUuhczj9vxlsdAEdj/hOc8pjUIXrroKUHonZDqZjnxQPiiXnNJFST/Xz595x8n/8THk2/PSG88vjUtjfQiCnpesl6Wr0tW8NPGO9SEkLfgrTSBpl0bz0lnJLbm6voBn8//k2Ht27AEqD6qF81KIWEsj@D47Pn4GyEZA@A382aUS8jcvXcB/yWGd/qpfIkQpdbtCh4ivLRhCmi5pJUnblSS7V92dfnV9U979qkPn12qt17HmdtgTiSr1u51arSb1Gpli0O0WmVERyztiA0Fubvr9x4cvDvv9Im43zJvZ/MN84SG8Wu18k38dZIZtFKjW3O4Kknz5@eef4/vzy4tLlqIJlvd5XJi@oAl4XWyou5jYoAKy3Kn2rm8URdnqSg2JtUSWLXAaZVHvzssjUhapL1YDS6xXcL7frSrt9m4Vrnf3lYJcwlJWoStOp9OuqNG1qUbPTlutQ983rtAflXcUmAy6ouH3u2Kn3Gu1alWsWynUdojnF2oVRVSUV3qzyUmUFcgWpbno@RK5vkn/ydc3TZm@FPxTFMzkn21FhmKlClfza3nelJsy5kEW1rq@aWOSwl1DqiMrPeXmhuXBp6w0Gc62AoLDBfj/p38vIMGUSJmbDM7nLtmpKrC8t5SdXXk/X@N/rW1ojCxWpAq0UZQMqdN5mKvk9nY6B71cLyc3c1qu2@4t2DlFyhBQ6kgJW3oGZShktMZzUS@LEiplAze1PcfSHFhsV2qNRa2Q@nJu@bWv1/K5/MNOrlZjtHO5d9swfgAdEBPhlQFFJjJptpuxdiUolTa8rwkXOKRvrkHhWBm4BzLfve5256UShW8MWtnrjHHToOjJjSg1FvSWopelBj3WEK/FrOF39J54I2avBzfoRuV0hc7W1Z1GI7fD0nv7DZg29RwvKUEJT0KBFRgmHcAwU6JmSSByBRrVGlhnNsw60wUZ5avVarEMn/MPdo/Kc6GB2//srEEsiGwgkf0aRZghQVATwFMfQMdfkr0SrMQcx/CJNxpts3xYcpCBZYHXZzkObpyhRw6OqTO8hFXgtpABgwP@KBTDa3JiWDPLupzNLq349cgO6sabN7CgpK/vv/31n8L79/D@Bfv@xX@rVfHz@2//w3/57je/hcx/hPf/hPc/fP/tX/@Uven1H@D9v1J5f@DvFBx7C4Dr337/7S9/9/23f/ENvP8Tf3@z/P7uV3/P/v83/8Pkb7/71R/wg10Arl///Lu//nNg8VeY/jNIwz/P/hlPpnJZ8mdREur97RLwz7//9q9@x9N/ngZJ5UPVn0H@b1L5PxME7MxtUt1TVU3T4AO/Vfqi31r2VQSib55hM8Iz3Lur6ewk08YakPKtmvATUIMJ3q2BdwuG6MjB@q4kaKg05XJtv7pfq5T31f3a/k5V361WVb2s6nv7e7WSCj7cvr67X63p6v5OrbKzs1NTiV6u1vbA33eH9qhYBP9DF0VCE7ZrYpB6E6P9PW3cFjJDawSLqC0yl4fKVmYYZZDZPhEr@90SEdk6TyYKucbJTyYBLPeBc7mkzsDkVw9m@@LunljPwbd4IFYgSRs8l0lJguErSl1RVDq13oG4VxXr4DcWpAf6ARH3arAA3NsTlYYIzaiK4i4p74nil6Dw1llBIvMDsXEDbEfyiBtEYKbUNAJvcOGwfNpiPMliTSZ0aNS6IjMcbBRKsiTtlSVJkRqAZFtMd4zSwAZC@1jzIv6QJ@CvBjNew7fCme/KtQJYYVKoKY0bxtK/SvHkn8OK0/Bx1UdJ1om4WxMxG0Cacg1JtauDXF3VC@pDgZmEXV3I3AhDjMbdqZFGrYG@I0xbzbaQlZAtqSJkChVvx8tks1lwQ1@0xYp4rPWbRe5HtovUieyiX4kumRb5qmBii4Jv4dHcEO/bZpP5fhVbc0aCTP6PfGlAogU4hQZaeTEzZfPMFbrbpMtYan6dofM9ObmOTl5mLt1Gqj9DWRv1U3qnQqdHlK8/tZ3r/UqhTRddMsiWgHRvTmuv9l7tv3r28vjl8ZOHpfp@fb/bXR5Tc/BEg3eKV9W/dj9qZOpTqbIjVcAlbWVYc/U9JdMu72mBcZXp8ZACeWdPIXBFTX1Zz4zQb0rcqxW3KpVac315MaEuPTCy/6Ph2Zld/tGz1@@yxaIkEaJnd78uNNl/Ez4eHbNul8XdqqhgKEbwqv@qnwGDTsRyFdUyXyTcZqcnuHnOpX9WLqB/lpVkBHAZXWG5peRgaf5FGSxHrba7v5sRfigWb9tDhdJ4U2FkwWJ7Nlm3q3Do288M3HFx450FSDybvbV8@AbdDzx7GJsYgjYGt83QyKTzuN1JZdFHEizmXQVFjJPAXDC/ePO6idtYZITjXEZ3JaQncCSHD4TA@BBFuBa2ANfMDGmIBXw0BGELTxTxUo7gVPIgCBU8mSkpwtYWG9kArAVhH5FjJZ5Z0BvCjYDiMYbDgOCGDz1oYUElBp7leVMWt@VcEVYpoNZRQN5yNB4E6aYYzpER4wJakyOUIuUcG8fIbzGwwWyErDx5@skR1CEtMqIbh7y26A/w3k3avO2RwomTEmQhFgSnkqLgCAjoIFOmuJUJRq6YMoXMEx3LR3QDEqBg9lApJyoZ8YodvOxBdUQ/Mh0vAMSMusxaQHJ9Tpa3gfNDGwEixNZRI4sJwz8zVd57eE9TpwczS3T2LmMpaZKyEp8WJ20TtqAvUIVHHobe0NvwLz2C0X/8OSEsDoedCQ4R36VFz1vjvqPP8IhuYKYPAaF8mJMh00N6jy3vNcqc3lNBUxrs3FiO4XhOwtuNkAvVSYP1/LQhfCybyjXudzW@njx4YL6adia9hjJphfidz09gCjmXbQaSC1uTFmjbtGP3GmEnn7d7rYnysYzXMDu1SgA8Yn0XKFxUIEi3BbzgnnigqG87buFrt6c@6bh5YHmm5r5svVWNVkmdw9tu6aqjftXSeTuAZth6m3cbRhPeuPW2cDYP02neaCwe10OVc9lpve0YvRbIw4GK@fwTaAzwGXScfL6nAHEHClcrNpwHD4y80543nEJBQahXlYMnnRASvXwLr@uy0ZwfvO3MoH5dhu8WkHEUYB7qcVnfxLwDfw2QMVORhHXG4xzZmwN7k1Yr9@VB7stca3v7bWdemPRUJv56KVEuZH6OzCdcg1bnvlTIkkjoikQWP7DrH2i5gIiqnc@DkNVpqibjMPcllEzz@YjrGzS/9EkQ0bYuahg/p2c3/9KbL@kpDT7ZBaOPPMzDgCGoexiYts3BWaTX1AbtNvDREiqsIdyCQSGwjD8rBQu784MDISLND5GBMtoqGCMGxmnRBxP4uD6iz90JTN/GZ8Dcbq7XWfXIhMfu4@nTL48IuKqV3dTop5aODrjANzsIglblunTTYAaQhQ6A7aLGCGCoMUK4AholFBI3OxyyxQvRNeUdBLXQ7IxY8DC9CRnNHVjLaLDqMJo4GzCY17Bhq29a1NSBPtmQInaT0oMEDBVhCxqBPGAb7B5pg10kDx4Qftlsgfu9h1MLgiHcm7yOQCucAvF7cAo4kMs3oKNoXikR4G0LSzDiZYHQzr@MEI8ak6FC/o3Kgse08heiiscnAQuWRLkpjA3si62tN/nWDmcI/qkLDfWh7OaHDPce6uTR8bOTly@Onj87PIVPvbyzL2QIdxnq8WNSVp63MMXnKAxsl4Z3mMZz3fqTj0xwh8C3BJXyhvhYniH56OUnsEz69LGK90GA6DH4zqLzcz3GZAX0PvNA8/yz4qV9bhcXH5sFldisQZ/QVaB7/uAjITt0rneSEM4kgjPABRxMLzx4e@GJThMrCPhjJArRg53ow6toMOsEYzJhFPLHTtBDuuicgZ5q4daASs9KffvMpk/rGTMEC/Xprfwhq07Hh4CPixgaoYEaLdT2S6U6KamY0KNEOUpUosROlKhGid0osRcl9qNEjSf0CLPOMOvl/UplN0nuJcn9JFmLkzulJJlg2CknyUqS3EmS1SSZUNuJqe3uU7wkE0mTDl3LxzJ9Zz8qwyBvN6SZVUCjL2fuAKPlFUiovrOSCfT2FzNhYc4JPS0eI1C5vJtcg/WJYFsy40plfKiMMrvimTBXCWwtRRX2yPfBKh3N8WE2oHRKnWCInSCA2SWmYxngDFgheCmtJ6D/llJnodr@VT2epCzE0NLja6huwaoV6uBz6QhXnzXF5XXFDFt5LTYWTU9iwaRiDDmTjMv6YvQgxbizkJfGuo0GFiW6AaLMILAPEi6dFM0X/mwtycrtJBcQriW5whTDW11XC2UjU@StqCqd/ym2VkSP@SkW7W1wA/hj4agOLHUoxuy3rvW6@P233/xX8v23v/wt@e43v/0///DvMf33@PHfwWch5RjgF7/Ej7/Fj/@IH7/Bj1@lKlH4Sl387pu/g8t/95/Jd3/6S1b0V78T1Z0YEZRgVlLz13@GH3@OH/9DVKsx4K9/zgCxiqjeCAuulQxQv/hHQoAaYomRffN7QsQ8OBgy17wOG@M9RVlCEIuhQ1O95XL2aY59FHtJyYuAl1/pyVUeO0BJIfcNfM5ZMvbAnWGhLWilTcMcYxgpz/IC9H9MdGG8QDsDfbscgtPD9yIkaP2/IXUi5REGsumtCi1mw3n7ebvFpBRh82IRuMOHtHBUmFZiTmC1LIB@05XAVaDhsoUucHWmI1y@n@L6KJpAxEiz7FDWFYHTimrDoofwh3/Bf7JyRqXFaYiF@tPHwgk8IlJPEVwwN0vdBlSWc2AFmgQkp6vSDGsyhS6BarG8UbB4QaWgLqNLeo4Pm6PjJ0sDBl8DcDHP0xYpJtQiongHLEqawyvocVUW4Rm/HKBTqld6Qjo0eh2w@MUXX4hCKq@EOuQPZYoh1ShmMuIifbGonCoqp4qAZ4aT2ppqubzEA5040C4qy8HgiyZqsVqiXDhyon5ANmAtyHYd1ZEzC8atVdTUIi8au1XkKZR6r8XHSdelNqdNRGWlAuBcrNNa7sv1qEsrMKsdtb4mSnshZ6G3NmNaqJMaFFR6wrKU4p7Ta@t6bpHgLaj1Xv6ehMqlfyGhwj0J7VbvJrTcrVh3Af1m@d5tdiIzEVv4BBkb@JmFCQqnxm9A9RJzhBz7NCkrsOQ55EuewaVH5DUPjoP8YnQj5MLT4vzU7ZG4iPnUCy22PfBw6sGSw0MvOPWw0nUP9uXPBj1zPd8K0vco2Cze05Xw/hfTO3NhVlPxhkybP7cQ79piNzwuzivxzMa90Efs@aeImgkKPc9@33btsN8H59MZKYkA8VIzMQhPEvDBqZBK1Zdj1/Z4Knt4I3mo3I2T@rus2gvbPJePp7xQAiKHBBZ0puXA4ouMDfMcHwFMRYJNpHcMoEc6CGUFhTj2Jt6Z5Xp47w/WXkL/NMGNDBnTKeVFJYZKzBRHfBEtm6qh8Kofv3dV8nFZNpS4fnkRwYIwVOIvyxgl668h199IjlWL6J2@P7@naX5Pb@d3ZPtBuMwzzcTdHvx@P9IVOcEAgAkblbvZUPkteSvsLLASZ@MDGVmFe7M4tAITpj/k9BBADzm4NgL9UOOrAK5ixj/bJP/bOzCqfnTf7qPO7OkV2JvJEfp@dIkW0FueXdOSAfypgrZnlVys2o/vSYsvdOgKTyUiNVwuxnLCwJxOLTeID2EjxHfovH02XtEhmom6j99rePIvVHJe3txFj/tDyzGurKHMIdUU3qjFzy1jSO3V/RqOho4aPY89hVMuqfqCK0Zj7ilQfYPKGOqFomxWKwZix9pDz/Yoh083y49u3C2bZtwEbbEzEM8HC5qh97rSO4ynV9Mrdp@Ow54dze0om39YT36Kty/dKRCQA93WlnU1IavcZj6fy3GT7jEjxLDaYpMxFD/CiMHwq334fiK6u6V0lyGu1Ip6ecE72dTj9m09ntKKSCeZV3I/lbxL6e6tcylVY8gSE/bo/aaQFcyPDMcxTTmNkeXc2mOeu2ITMA97zHM3zCr9NQY1rkktXYiPxGsx/0IRbEg@he8L@P4MvhEhrEH7TKGitqFfG2150ZKJMU15LTynY6IvmpKikj5HTEEJURo3cm9imuZGmuYKTXOBZjwCFkmmgARzgSTvBeye27rAsUbhBuuMRbhyh6/bzDa8XM/w8ez1WrKluq0S6UKqg0GWLKl@JINRloZS/TFNBFL9lCbOpfrHkEjGlvROqkfDAgF8uKSJh5jPTThem1L9kazcCPQXAyK6mlSP@xRgDtgllcgN214d8CACL95VtSyVOZUqQY0J4MvDZnV6Kn2X4J@C8gdIQOF2i5RzFBgXIAuTRmrGYHRg2tDoA@DlddNHPdqa4vsbyR4KlOdbqU0V1JIZtUdSRlo0RowxLKWbj/ANDKLdrK/niOgrK7O72OHUQUNpJy/Sp9LTqD8wlGl5B4DTmzhOUj/qr0UUrAPvxydW3sTnCjsROcoRBgMoa9hCob6WbmkU9vUiL7z30z20ukeAnViIQFgvUbQpmw4@HPqmlNjUmy4qCS3F0z47XQdffFCi9i5Vo1aBj8wNxTSbtwwNQ3rwK7c1J1UPWVswQVjYKfXYKIvnBWqLsSixdSlPlQ0@YCFlc4b0RkYL1fYxT1I4Zm5UOldsmoaiuowktVyLZhIqaxjXPjNCRj05l8Fo9/dbvkY1wQUHHhFBqmZMhdlX7z38d4/575FDHQlhicA6x3r9VLrqXt86yy5x7iRkVzsQC1XyWFnrHMUUEpHD6iDlmd@maysuPj4jmTn5jGiMfcnbj8QWrwnukNvy2oLhQi/Bv1jMPMeN2fPyZkGteiTOhRY5LRpS4nhYw2NOk6bdzitr@LouxhKco@HrvTvYX@zgdOchPtoAf0nkbJTjjxTQc4p4bOOeeurkgp06eBh0Fj8mJJUJ5p6Gw8UhWpBx3H/@@PjTT/4EJt29vT1l9SgCRy3UTeZx4dZjgnjZUlbxRm76yzsYOzH2/HC764ortoQZa3AGDHpuw9SPj3GF27KUPV8au1CPwaYkynGdJ8PAWLBK6OoYOGXbXK4hCMQK5ZzBkUTuLchbpas1PDVC7cADnX6fTl/9Pgbn9Pt8FsOuiY@Rfsjw58CXk3iN6HdtomimDT8dhhsAswn7qRy@Acfvg2RxKBn8oaT4h8fiWjM3tKNgB9wfwiOqODJCrugK@32lKIf9DBKG1JbxtiFSruJtQqwWQuPGJ43U5HS2maODz9gKpp7LfyfpnP2WFn3iVxBtvVK2Z@6lQcNAGBV6d1OKIxaQFZ2L0R@a8Vz69Cj8VR/DZVvIkWxUYp1p9MSnXIMlx7k9Zc/5iEM/AoVWogzTGC2Q8cCxJvhjL6C7a3aTn9nQK@Mn9tkZKFKRP5COBbi8wN9/KXijwqPo/tUM@Yz@ZA9/8hGPCaOPBuP7wCBOeeEG5ICUd8Gbqqkg2eQNgsUwGYI3GZdokBaFgvcefO2x5L6aqrstXymL33r0UhDfttzHnn3HZgroHQdU3k3Jmb7epbem@aEltQOpk8voXnqBP/ugRc8pNYxRm8piRoyeMIBJFjZhOGZ0a66MN4XXhS2XGh6MACMmi60BB9dFp40erylxhKtLPiCVMv1lDKBHvVRKFnCwk70F7FAGVZFZFt3HDYz4wVD8AA8Tha0M2kKma1g/UmVM02cgJbpMtjk6dqCCQ5kNgeiimrqowFJjaw3hbVnMA5a8qIgLmACen35sMcu7WhWMovJ/AQ)

Languages that should be tested separately:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse (73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)  *Still can't run SYMBF but it almost certainly works*
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>  (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- DOBELA (109) [local](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/dobelx64/)

### Explanation

Pyramid-Scheme is a lisp like language about ASCII triangles. It has a surprisingly flexible syntax.  We are required to have a pyramid on the first line to serve as a main function.  Pyramids not on the line or connected to another pyramid need not be well formed at all.  Luckily we didn't have any `^`s on the first line to begin with so we didn't need to make sure any pyramids were well formed.  So I added the following pyramid to line 1

```
  ^
 / \
/112\
-----
```

I used `x`s to properly align it.

#### Whirl

We added 2 new ones so naturally we broke whirl to fix this I removed 2 `1`s from the del|m|t code, restoring the balance

#### Del|m|t

Removing the 1s changed Del|m|t's tokens so I had to add a `B` to fix the token

#### What

I had a 2/3 chance of breaking what, and I did. I added an additional `?` to the beginning of the code to re-balance it.  Remove this if needed.

#### The 2D langs

A lot happened with the 2D-langs here I broke pretty much every one of them.  I'll spare the details but it was a lot of re-aligning, hair pulling and swearing.

#### Turtlèd

I broke Turtlèd but couldn't figure out why.  Luckily Stasoid was kind enough to fix it fore me.  So thanks @stasoid :D

#### Cubix

All this activity caused cubix to break, I moved the capsule as per routine.

### Going forwards

I've added a lot of space on the 2nd and third lines, this can be used extensively for token breaking incident, it might be worth moving a couple of existing token breakers to here.

If you need to add a `^` to the first line just make sure it forms a proper pyramid.  The smallest pyramid is

```
^
-
```

Comment: Link to the language?

Comment: Incident tokenizer worked incorrectly. It reported " #" to be token, while actually it is not.
Incilite shows that it is not a token because it overlaps with "#\n". I think tokenizer worked incorrectly because it read polyglot from command line.
I changed it to read from file instead, it works as expected now. Also I fixed Incident.

Comment: Thanks for disabling V, I didn't realize it takes so long to execute - 50% of total time (13 of 26 sec).

Comment: Ok, I am confused now. DJMcMayhem said in a comment to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102417) that he doesn't know why V is so slow, but it is quite obvious - there is a 100ms delay between each key stroke in v.py key_stroke(). Commenting out `time.sleep` drops execution time of entire polyglot (not VAbstraction) from 6 min to 4 sec.

Comment: @stasoid I just reported this on the github for V with a link to these comments.

Answer (score 7):

## 122. [Monkeys](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Monkeys), 4540 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉QQxQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoO\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #7E7E7C",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #00A2E7",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002500 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4652 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaUnhpT7c0qY6FhRpJegQHaY1XR3o3IQ2h5xJCwbPaYJBq1NTm5q0Ku7PFaELE3UkBTDjRFIGAGUKuqYLJkmO0i1F5ia9PvcqIbZbmqZDskHnBfmXyS8mzauTCaf0DQCM0/lqtlDOvMqfoK9V3RAQCy8YhopxSXpREPhXgCn6mtMltZypnO@kWIyp6Wp/yiPd5lCAdKyqKMmCQfFA1Rmt2ewNYoA@oHWB61tglKjqNGahJ2OZlmhe0@iezA2DPC1LAFsMJWkBWUOvIP2ANtSJsE2AQSuC0KcNTeAlUeJJqbSwMAXFkFTFCNISP6bnkizTfUGGDBtSeD8go6fGVpRVcJDqqxQNH157Rfj67lAAGEVwKi9owBusvIqMBE44PJjrnKYBkcDABhBuShMQBcl0G7TAGRKKGmQxBKVP@KathVClOWW7lvRM4mgO6J3qBLch6CZUL0jw0kNBFwAlt5YFz1yXTGABsjVD1wROp5u6IHh3RXKnSChMxRJMrEiQNNvpqbtQLbqh@awcQU4zqQM90ry5pDg6mKYPn07gm3a5TqhCJU9/OXzAsCWE0MSa7uG8dPo3tME8PAjwXbA9ZqC/UICVAq7INKNqJsMFNCAwYAKBDIdBDAVm4aAmbxVMn75qiy2hsqD60Bp0SaHbflIzfqrr2Ms2TOXGUGlZVQbAT6isPlWQHwodD0ET8Cr0Ez8tzIBrqmK1kTonHG4OJWg0A5uE6wGDOB55b2kKwlDQFSB7Nkedcg1VnhI4yGmYKIDAFciKGEsi3aZFTpIxC6QjKotqXTCmsol5pkofWx6UgdAP0g4ZvNpHoIk6g@I4QEoioA9NtnoeIQqAoSFUUlVM@t2//nf9wQDwZHhe1fu2uLbpvsoTncYRYkFb0CiwqsLJhCyA82PpVnYoYMbJUp8zsXhlaRdBiCClztWp3KdVKFCfS9C1htwMuqMoCrwpWEJuKUI/PeHGlr6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodoD/noJV4gTogMhOYTE0xSQe0Au02mJ88n449nz4@CECcN@g9OmSYwQkIXPCIRMGd@2uS085sGhTKMkzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkKUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhKPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA8wQNEhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK7/dp1Df0KIwp2VOGUy5AVpCCmTheF7QTFtfQU0MEzTS62GHRAbsMTRoDKnDz6/LJmOJPbpulYG63mo9e0TkUMnY5lBABp1Kc7YtR/clHbSTvHxdOgDMXhXu@hlBdgj42fUOCY4hAEImLAR@aoJyA0GeDyV@CLKL1CmWerTGotfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aCSGPfsxTAWZdRSS8S6KALboWzwwxiKqs50I0vjbEV/HzBmTPYjVNYkwHmzFBhkuCLJnMw2spwZabjDYOKYS6Vlrc27NT2AwdHXopiAsQ9PUjGPQ7ZI5nPaC0KxMU1@WzKqCLcuY@lIyVSvck9Ue6FIDOhPjlMDw0560eFUjErdm@MigZmA0iQadhtH2eQoi4nGLBmg5Ep9D4K0kF9G2BIX16wJAAhQETnlEg@jPImiAxlLhPa4gkfsg9BCXn3ZhL3N5IYC51nzJqRNUGXSHDOZonWV1UDMiqBZbURM9ze0dntYKm9hibndwpEqK54v748eP7mP3Gajjjx8/QegUQ58w5IPQJxIKkBDCBTFEcvhJCFPvSQ6Me3S/3DuYF95HbLYFDiUrSfNw98fHkUc/d8/a1zBevaCXQA0BdAAvgMftTacx6PW6zuZQ0WBPtGpftzjbJ9JQF5QBJSw0VTfpSjVfeKplmhdpFzM1dEaWeowCg@HTBLobTDhce/LDzMHJDsG6qppp0mAYT6CLAGTPmShTnUIHhcmCNJHMEpmiyAqK9qbRnNQclGshKG1PSERdnazVi0EJ/FClXYcRFxrSO5M8HHPt1CimTu053lZ8AuMnOEUL8tSA5@mAat2uI23AJALivC0IMyhq4PMhJJnHrSNtyBRBiZO5oN6zyN8zNbSB4wjcV3uCvIhHA4IsBs3FKog9MR6lrAsd6L8HsScvtVjty0CZ0K0CC/FVAudMMJugy8tgutNlySCz6G2OU2vZe6BcVt@I7Gpp1yYlvDGp9tuBrm0sRE6grcYqaqJN6AmMntgOCpi@vs0pSsaQ/OyAvqHobQrJbUx6IvnZA3Bs2xZgqOBEF1lyidMkNG9UFSbFcwI2URXVIgVYJSkcUyeXIAxJ@@jZ1fw7xPQEcQpTJ6YnKRj@BlgglSSQYq8nvQcKfEHSneseMH3a28c2EK7hG@OA3mG8OdVNWejb1//2x31ogLfNM@SWYPLz43XgCfiGTRUQ320tOyvekJ/9LUtgRlNZ4ggbSOhbKHkOp2WcvA7sR43ajg4EhpwOjbt0GheEE39g5PqKnFmU64I87QvOdX8hhMW7JoiVW5EmpEZwRXuKDFHvZH9lQFn5cVqryyrXJ1is5QZJ2LS21S7CghtA5ZgtjQTK6jvodOwcerO@ADaCObV@cUnhW@0qafj9Wn@1IUMxrscKMBnjetI7XEQi4u/JtdVdcEwPiDI3toJPGNxfVasyujQYgC1jX98DAysTJgIaxwvMnFzeVTHK1NCspsDQV/DpsvX7HoizrLkOvAcI1ZTJz68ROyIIPPQNJBWX9AJbLJJeMVXmeku0e4a/Xn6wQDJ4gnpJ8z5fKILj6HoOuFk81LT38@MwTfKnUvtzW@uMBAGviqIgfKvPwrgjTTg5EO5vBd9VwY6duAntAR1xMw4sSJkzQEBMm83CDJqF/HxNaHEo4acyp29CXxHZDTnOVP@92eImjybxqizZkuncvKcLX5vuGzS4gkx@Nlnx7i1/@2At4zAdWIf2d2iVN3HG9o4cfYd6siZLOB3dEoyg@h7veHWO33d771CdCdbv/iFrtZeq71A/AZlIBszA3mbv898SV1z6Iz/7uTjeS5XJy3vjj@lrVdVhtmzQ4WAIDRyFrFfDgC3L1oSwWaq@L9OGJKsG3SC/X@MFWOWGYf3ul@ZttkmcEuCHVh9bh/dn20sUGd7oDPl9p3E5eaDK8eSA4eDnXQmY6iJqefv6vRpuraFY9psaam3uqAprX99V7WP4/5ZwkJVIHef8W8GvWFH71Jk9V3y/gjAjwFW3/ZUrhpIkZ5CxplLvNYDOD@fc0rn@I0aP97jrjB7akhjLYM1hhlQSAqZuGdD/mNKiXy@t/3066g3axLcqsdW4Y1kAjU1@3zQpHQ6xvzIHGwp9v8YS5akwFfZqkGpvJIDYfE13fD9RIbsah/ZiAgPMw83JNdTKngp@F9U4nuPdVxUOJ0vQyb9pzexVNRpY2BpOnWsQqGHgbcaBMtV2GneLd/WpUv8654aa07PV/g6RmPJrNVLy2zbTjhluCOS7X4Ec47Y6THjVCdgQyne0v42UrNNYvzuIScwG80jCJSD9q3iP6fXiINivYI9Aq0pjI4DrSN@neMLvzdQJcCoFczFFMJf4@x639ynSnqrKv6Z1QJ/2JTTTwPjEXfpvtdIx3VhOemC58ZuVy@9oAWeaCNzCKfG7DVsDlOZ34oy8XXj7yii1tQy3t@RzVT47PftGo9ex77LBZDDxVUBnuYtxAu90QYIsFYx8j/mjOTYtWaTEhU1rKXPjTXDwSr1oS2CM1A8Y/FCYCOT2KwY91x9NDefyLtBCxe@e5CBDliX3tqkkmN/ga8NUFcH4KhCpl7PAubec0oQbCMVvys5mCQE38Hhd2gnuX0w4toSdh2zfUAzWxE5VxsLScK6vENpr2cRRYb2XZfhtDwuIk3R7P91YO60clBReF8jOlrN5Qh/gftt0AhM1U9WDNIHzeDifz@ulrExo6w8UAHOgiNsA7iVaHgkGDTMwk8BKIn1/Tx9@WRyHjtkXOk27jl3046OFlexqFRYa2e@vW1nvD7nH9KE7EHAfuh@UYzrkJqCCDKbXXlBuB06UyMWic1N1WuEmZPsSw05NT6w9UpgRoRvCkFP6skC3QJeQeaKqWzt91nZyE5cG/@vf923vjIEAlZxIBgy1AwU9itSJMFTnn6xy7dIzmsahdwfimA9x7QtLD@QytDGXTOg9xCkDJmytYjNp7/Havk5wU0OB2qLCalRUY@h5YFqNZlHTVwVLdOyC17mcSsGUeDpR6LnUN4dGEKY3Ci@QPeT1xgOEEEwxdRVFz0@X6L6ASzN9JIz0XVlVx2SHBCn5r39v7WxDooQihGGneOLYslUijfqIbCfzvDoFqh0kK0FXbRAPMhkm9lMc9UDwBSveS/NDjmy5gyQGnA1nLMbadM5lGnSgQLvRMQt3xk4k0XOYqZ@370OP6d/QE0b4b3/MeL/YfHP9EEiwhstPOyAnLyhX28khSN6kumnX4cJlVwtdgIjHy1qobDc9D4ZJczkbyBPiPUTkTpiTDWTiJaDggIhuOYoB/QNuvQS11WnSh56ppYMDDZOOofca6DcOQpa/EXHEwM1QzHK4oH@hhygrAZ5mYyG4sxgi4/77JJ11FtYj23sfTF7oTclK4CwcDEfSpDqHT2kYnzCkC30V3WHuf3qYPzKGw5WHh8UPofAC2KbqAP4jgz2nUMl/OQyehX75xYDJjsv14j6xNoGgex9@qZVqhUYz02w1gI0vVi0Piqo@4TYqAoVAk2EaOlRl4mAE/NAlwfi22vhA9Ab1wQb0eOhDjj4F858GDfVhrVhstroCrkMraKURTbKTbZPvw27GVzk/kKyb1NfJomQTZSshvLdlp0ZkxhYPt7GtLP2OGGETQM@egnZ2WADi92WP0iNMcdFpYEsA2ELA19Ve3@1jz24qgbea7ROJgLaza7QNtp9ju6g@vMa1H5XFwg3YO1A2A50PMtIixGaKlcfiwF4OvfwzsUWDoe6fiy0E17fZgmD7oRw2vGULZKa@VbUtSoqZUrlVL@yp2Dfq9OHDHixvkHzYro4NtQcIyLc@1Lo@zhC@cZctLMCGgiFGJMrDcryzOpNqO3k5OheG1KHlCsLJm1HDoGeSIfVkgXQvEcc8GdQm6huy1WGg3qRRRQfpjGzAGNXvg9LtLU3U2TBYBcnmtrXDHVBo1wEwJrg2Ify0i0JYI/3W2Qd08hxmQvzPVuZDAkcwG9Qe58QHgfndv/53lkPigwnhP7XDIoT/lRX@iUEGvXWqsmhcswbZ0i7VaAMMAaviE26xVScci3Gsl5QptPYEODgjDEFwi9hNfTd4PPdt4Cc0AjATBxUcR0h5gv7oQS@bY4ZB02mgymKQbJAKC2gHGIaI083zFB1EYehj4rF4lGWAyMDMQRiQLIQBzULo9R6DXFEzSUv/3OPp09NT2mXAjFhIx08sRjKH3E8R189rQg8BlrKsrHsa8kCWTQ5IO7OzeQ45H@vFrKg93KybfjwBA8pqFxiDPSQAIF6MVmx@uGCQV21WQaMrwsIk49XSsR7BdFOIs4VguQk7iAKAyMKNfoyvZXez84b@CFvSHNxuBlcHwRoIduzaJzr3P9EP5oPyaLuz0iAw/2GPICkQ/rM9Pq5r6cm89a70vPaNxNrQnxuKinuxRaCW9oSZcIRh496tnuKyUQG92C9@AZTQE6Bn8YI0UjUjkyuULqu1xhvvQALpfg3mpt1np76HQNB//7gOuF9JvcPUbJFpXGeLDiu3qdosaiDEZmXjNZn7SntN6Tuld6xtz7dlk4Q3BbGh70VMZoqBIln8e4t9k8psAeasbZk3pXq8X17uH0/PHpSDN8X/ss9x@iB4hMIFoQeDuE276T06p@Rs5jbxYRUj6PgFhV2bxwLWjknW/Sb6fZ/B9aMvG89BZ9sY/QbDZ0xfmDHKVJap4DsbylD3IGMVRZzmLMIcekHXOKSySOqmQJ56sym3TQ1t1@XtUzq2r9WaSVVr4k0cmDkF5ly6xFvQBlHQ1vSceNvCBK1kbuZ0ME/EpQcydV2SaRqoivUmV18im6Gc7jiBrVMawkQKNB16UHFs/ABBkaF/2xDqJku9Ey59v6DXblFfcxEMGposmR70zVsEcfoLtfF4sQLsqSyga99p6tH2I6Qddz8f8RisTYFfNVWjN0sOecEJ1WHWSeengBzEQKAvpxOAE8mlLuAoIdAVNQCZgY9uh4h7KMVj1yE46ceg9OBQWPSlAYw0Hq8fVNIPLLvxNeS8PveD4gY9bLHqHHfvthnzq/wjtzjG3XNBSekLCw86rh8/Incg3j3vzNxe1xsZIE6atsdm/7W3pqMsONPutRtPx1cKIZVaK4LdvpNKBYcGhW5rMHGCEhumXoYgjKEeccJptGdK3F0NOkiTW8@DR/Ebpu6lA2c4ns1phfb5yJQLLiQhSJOcIglJMq5WefCJDg@ThnbGWEPp42UlafQ9Gww@QpgU4qUPcbUkB@YGrjN4KTAuIcsxQQsDMPwdI0VzmFwiRdb1kBRL4VKHDlB7k0lHHgxJBwRekFrTZz/SG22w6YEWV1OpY7s1dtVhigaxON2jMQDtHjXnWJzAX9v3CLiGSgygcjCJlkChfL4SFAX6qwdkZgK9k@amIGS61@88I@jfPKlCSjiwSLywnZmA0N0nWAruL7IK9swhc0Jm7CcvMO7//IADv2gP/Uvmj5ggc/LFcyinlwwYY94zz@EwzfoiRz7foXLkOVTQHPnxR5zovxyCtfMUdAVdCwAKHMreE5BnsI7Sh8rJIXfqOeynw0ckB9z6fN4vkOE3BhP8csi9MIc/gjXhhxjd6p2eQ8OL3SEUDLIvQB/2kEPGDzLzxeOiXQt8EAGLP5R8PqQhePiEBPyGeWj4yLjy0GDI0sKJbeQyg4mjRnZtlXVLvHls0WKgHX281ugx4pRqLWs/OcDbD7DsSdtnH/3hDwdsHKZMn@IRj/opHPl4dEAffHYxRy7d9eUhPztx33NiOPj8WBvXarfeB4/7IFd1sVEX1OanE/qIoQ6Yo9AvCYb5@eefwfqk78@CZ8FH733A/XjvWZwlEkcn/njyyP/Zz7r9Jwe0zIZY1usJh70M/dCgHxIcd@SLhj8rJ5IkaUa/D191iI9TgSWWRin5AB8PW3O7YxF34yf00P706SP8kX/4rG/x9yOJsaMJyNvPRy/teV5QB2cfbm4WN4vv@TzBt5olwTbDsuEHnLFF4h8/f4AqCz7yOT7@TOYxtCuRdKnqZwSmhwcsG6PVAxj5FgLdoxeLAH6oA36xOFhBInuwhD8WP/mDp4MFTR38Jp32fednsQ4Fg09OiDr4@fTn9D/hQx3APOPg7Ozx5cUXuA/@hMgffQHf6f3pafDsbHEWeDy7pw6@UAeLF@og7AJxeTiiDtKL0zqh4D5/ZtPybE@CyxA@DTzea7VyIdMo@MOngYNwMZPzhxut7AELd7HNLSZG8LZeyOSrraY/bOU6L7ULrRrEG49PZ58/@4LAyM/Bs0cgZfGD78yXNk2Tvns6CtJf/zxZF2YdWidQB/mzRYsJnAK5ZTumTsoJPMDdgxdK@4U6uD@493wKfwqH5NAsxI7Z8bVa3fxXqxAvLUIjVQ8NQ0O2D027CAmt0DK0XIQmapXtQ1CAv9AEglJIXIQGISWksOwOHrX6EK3Gq59fRa7/J1X1uqoCQhUym4uQibhDIlwH1eo1oBSh@BH8SaEQUrkIzeA/JBNZY396CnlDDw/UPe36WYC@G2TdwZA7GHe7pcdYXHv@8hKOP9@TkT2WerwXFpL56KL97qeH@1Qq5X48OWCMhwfGUmeucNR1giAvL09P@Uwz8/TE4ELH4vTQ99kX@Ayf9Jnv1L58OuifIVODpx8fKLdn3ul08NuZz@ZWiASsuM46cfuGBOAzeyfvbmCxXww8nvvY45cXr9f74cF94rZq4vHQAtirHhf7sAiLdNjlJYZsCkYBNoK2RjzmPTuLx@A@nvQGPCGSbGV5cGma9uAKkolxkLggpNMZXeeWBCgKA9GDi9OfHlz34cd0OhUj0bFAKk6reiAV8bq83p/Y01O7jLAXol3uhUvV3fSXl@0/z5eXUw/5ePHP68VI@/fM64FkbwzuFl88i1PPqQfjIApzfXk5wyCB@wKhe4/30fvyYsXBr8d7auE88wLvcPb/z/ivGrSh0e6DlwM0IBQ6GvN6ekvBG417kr6U/Zf@CBXwuCLuCNTL5ebc9/efjyJHiej9p8ejxyPP6VHw6OHscUc9e90HNMiyI3tp9gD5Rh0ET@ouNuxyoyye4AaFKgtBGWb3kdTJrjC4nzxHrz9JNuU78n2@P0qlrLKPjn75SNNeQAeFueBzAPJLe@jTs9O1UG1Qes/g@4W2mQzhly8gZ1Ya2CMeeyfi4WERChH4k1768MsB93JC0NMvLvfJjrgS9B73Cdmicn1xHXL6PfvoenEdfum9oN12xHqJeRCLnpwcRa1wInkCwzR7ZKeEIMVrLWLGIEUwOJ503JMDlCY3sNwLlUr3hIEEQ5y2wyNfLBZjwvC7@CFeCC@oE9zKsfaNXAGX1X/oZIrgO6ANI0XB1KAHDT@nEyEYAGWZ02lVFD9a8TDHoXuCAGamIMu4UodTALCE5f4cpp0fqQPQM2AAGwJ8JjVOmArCfDqdC@tPTjKOuRHtGcEUFj@//@1f/Qv4/j18/9y6/vn/kYrh7@9/@z//b7/7m7@FyP8C3/8bvv/597/9t39sfcn9P8D3/9mK@wf7uwVnfSnA9T/8/rd/8Xe//@2/@mv4/q/2969ff3/3l//J@v9/7T8M/u3v/vIf8Me6AVx/9We/@7d/AiT@JYb/JYTh347@Uzu4FWsF/9QJQr5//wr4z37/23/zd3b4T7ZBtuIh659C/N9sxf8plaBbNfipl84vmlvXZiGTu6DidLZayb@6xGygGF0uFJvr24SV6mSNrVF0C@Xy61v7QnXVKc1zKAoCzdGWvuRguonHOgTpU@qsUWhCdLNKJ5Pr@wXeR8LkvtbC@1KFXpLbW7zWam3D5VIpFNOPdCzh9weDQfjBq598yDV4@JMDwr5vOhxQ17gMmmKt/XYJc0BIF1K4wwjSPVfIBm8Pnyyeau9HwgWjMKhLgyFMvubqGsAwDBjW1sPcm0GvQ11Ab5rg43n4HLeJ9jfMy0NUEPteOJxKxpKpSDjpT6aS0Rgbj8X8bNjPJpKJVMgPlneSjSdjKdafjKYi0Wg05afZcCyVgHma0pdEhgErjnW5aBKQFB4fjjnFp4zU4PCMOugLIkx@P9ALT9/74aDvRNDTJO2KJB9CtIthYHo/5PSjxf1j@osrHKETUALN0i4/5VrRPH2QKMBfDm97eJtNJjLxCN4@4S1YKqFcCG/7BDiULGYTeCtYqZlwgdyKeFss5kLFIt5WrVv84O3SuQ0BKhcPdz2Z48cQHkB4oIPSgfCCxE8FCKoQRH8YxeQIdl5Yvv2srKTedyVVl9V@tVeFj5U0GDgpg@r6YyXt/ZAkUVQBypqAqHh9qi7UJzup6iRZ12qVf3pyvZxgC5BFEg/tpb@g/eahDWklgKx6Qv4p2CyxT9OkK55wHR/B1fXJFYHgwkOH3DAKudwPLpf3PvX4yZWIuY5hshVw/8h@gilNynXsSiRcMEq5wiBIMZcrTocTLtcdaG5hEHDTn1wnLyA3jkCuJYoGQy8YpOEL0x5M19IWPR5XykMTFZ96cFkDoDWauD1udyLsdnvdJ4DkI@3a6obeE6wc1M2qmkOgC0gCAlNgr53ogjnVFU8qANYEHUh5T14skv67LZr08bFhcjoul5Aij2lXPOXCaAA5TVllncV6R8d@NuD/TFljW5ylDl6oPj6HEU3RJ6kTnAOBzXV6ZlN3RS8TA9/FFr0n1KEbKXZHdqzQA/J7SNMwmwhE1Kh6cHh4CNOu5pkr4qoGn04ZewJ1xpCZ08PZiS8dzfnIXCTozM/OyCTm9ScapXQBHQ/6eBSNZdUmY8iXAW0cALoT3z/mE4Ry04CUOkHDx3WgWabXEme79INF6@lvDojZS9e@OLufU4Us5R5fY7Nxxw3ytNv9I@39TUWSvyQjgTOy8OGBZqKhoV4aqZ8SPyV/um5VW9Xi59Bx8jj58PB2CkcdGL941Rj7G@Xy5OBYc0ei7ghM0NIHVn3ZhPfgLJwIGtzy4NH2mPJEEyA/NNwT8yfMHoid3c9852Y2IbNYKCn5R/3BQAr/0fXPvxwyjNtN0@xh/DeBU@v/FH5yVasIVzzm8qInmfHT009PBzCZT9GucAwl2MfQlpmybVR5FkcK@ROODPInCJsIA26dO0wXvEcMw7TDoOZTqXgyfkD9gWG@tlEBqeuVO1EQdGM62bd0l9Glaw6XNZX18h0ErqcrQYercyCMMx7QOCDg2jSOCNtx9iCxFUXOUdqNWxoM@nlhLEVhSCKnbNEi6gQPmugm2eamj/AUK/Rv81JfqA@Aa8qbxEUMfk4o6gNu5@Otx4Hz0z8aphe3P0Ne6sMHSwsAcNAwnxA5ZrIjA@wJ9UIhe7h@36BxVZXsZlpOcRxumKua5eYrL2krk0G0qDW4EX82LHeL4CNatKiA2hzRpERCOVbOKv6DBdabikhKsVQuQB46TYtkdd7O7dJ7eAQCqd5H0WsXTocgCrEgOOEUAUdAQAeRHoLbO0HPO95DIH00i@kiWeUHKBjq/YQSPy3aGe/x9hGyI3qRl1UDEFule6wa0EdPdrF2HWx6SCWAhVg7opAxwOkD3m@3Hj74ev8II5Dj9ePBVPqUDnvX3h42LmgM66gxkpGf9C3BIWdL2Gwm2NhHPzTtieVN4VnD2TEbRr1QR6Z/cmI1lXZCXXl47xdcBT75zeTHH/mftPvJ44l3kjbx6vNNYHwYeyQL5MhMT9IgHtq99Hhi3vt80mN64r3y4D0MPekQAIsWsw2vXTeouZIGWnCnyPD6V/dK4DfKo794r/iA5Kn/6C698nPpkH8BXynN@mX/c5q16wFlmumVTznhTuGLC9I7zjAwVvq4k13/GMgy9sjp1T33mAZ@yJDR5ytCZYBO4172@R69ULgMiW8znsg//sj55LPFiRwIeBHqp8in4r0JgUdfGu@PPdzp4tPqfgr5jz1wTUMxsheIh3w2r1/WtAN9J8Bjq003pFs0LpC8BZA3SaeP7j4d3R2lP35c3S8Ck0e/xf7j0EYakPgFEr@hGsTw6M5Lv2IJmTZ7XD9Ixz8EjwywLCWfD5js17ZyWhQe3UGKBgOeTfUL6ktyApKz2YESZnuvWGdWkEfqyfSDHNRkkMPpzD56KELejMFLkg1uuZZqEtjxHDpj@2GiqwQ4AoFp9olsmPiw@PSJcoq2XSugZFQuPZzvwHyAHMij4ySenO5nuVd/S7/uU8OOzl0b543SXYGGiUAkvtVdiWoiHc7Q@XsEQTXwJfRyYmksy6EGlA3RHgBDtAfCBVCLIJNsPWFDpu1EtDntBoJcqCdEywccT2QwUD@Betv0fFAhFhnQmfeQIflHaaKbQJ4kCNHSKSkPAtBVqA9QCaQB6yA90megyOgff6Tt29M0TD0SOBYgGMKNfCwCvaEUCv8OSgEHUjkCGUV9SAoB2j5gCrqG7RQU/acVZLupeiCDb@S3vFWD4VuXHzcVDcs7G/nmtcjAtvjwYQQmok0Q/BP7GPJD2ssfDuzh/pjOVa9hrlyoX2ca8MuGo8nNoW/H6@PB3pwzpOH5QT1JIU5PPFdnhe4lD/YLWHsgUmofD//r05etMkxCK3k/PucGrD@wJvQwoB6vMQkGOT3ECKr6gJlLY4nZPfYTD2oj/lXkhNGAc2obkkMGZ3njM75xGTdwLg6Duf1wzs65kRPBMOzjkwLO8ZHkiEziPT9BJ3DohfZxS2Tr2tl9I3u9uH7lJx4EMF2XyJmAQwvBTn5yMo5pZSf9g8JjkvqcyaFEU6lkKHRMh/wYYJ1A2AlEnEDUCcScQNwJJJxA0gmk7ADrYGYtzGw4GYnEN8HEJpjcBFPrYDS0CW4wRMObYGQTjG6CsU1wU1p0XVo8SfDSBw43SdcVdExjo0knDZ8LUUwSGQM07OvIKBAafgMJ2aNvIqG85G5kIhWyCyoxVQQKh@Obe9A@DmzaY1Hlt@jwWyVbd3YkjFWUNbshAlvQddBKhQUe4gZC5z2m0ceVokDt0rwscGAMCCZYKekiyL/gPbaeDdGXx@tBSkAMaXZ9D9kFmJJCHpacR2iJz57k8L5kC1t4LzbrARx6zZgtj2GbSIvK411XYIIxuhO3jfUjKljk6DsQYQsC22BDpbxVZlOf7i0y8vUidxDuLfINURbe2L5cyBsPQZ52spLxn2BLO@VZdopAWhvMAPvwWSIDrxoUHxJKf2GPXb//7V//7/Tvf/sXf0v/7m/@9v/7z/8Thv8T/vyfYLPQ4TXAn/8F/vx7/Plf8Odv8OcvtzIR@Mix63d//R/g9n/8j/Tv/sVfWEn/5u9c/ugaEaRg1CbnX/1L/PkT/Pm/XP7YGvCv/swCxCwu/wu1Y1p5AOrP/wtNQ2mIZY3sr/@epl0@MDA8tuTdW3380et9hWDNhnsSenydbv3yQx3ZHvL6XIDXvmM3dz5sAO8Wcp3D01Q3fQ/MGcvhC7U0z/FDdK62o1QD7R8eTRjVCA5A3uZ9MHrs1QE31P6/p49ptw9hIJo8G5W2dLhdf7verk0qwvpcDFCHZ57ZqDDsXVMC01sK5JvMBJZGEKctZEbKWjJi87eCpzU7A4jLkSzJ9LBeyi7LyQ2THto@9BL@N1NdFFochqxni8jhs5TtJ8xuFbijbl41G5TyOgamjJvHC7azkghhokGTQLY1v5GxeEO44H@NbtNydrcpVIuvOgx@emBijrc10rqgNO1yfQMWOW3De9HiiuzCW/TaAPeh48gjtf2cwz5g1@3trYvaiguhDOl9D8GwVSlLZayT2N2k8FZSeCsJaLZwEl0TC4df0UAGDtSL3tePduyqqN1sG@HCnuO0A5IBc0FrIdAvylNjmH6LmmjkXWX3FvkWSvYxbfeTB4XonDPa5X2TAXDu5km/bsv9qENvYN421P6cyO2dmJ3Weh/TTp6tTkG4R73m0rrl2NS@ltst8Cuo2UffdxYUDv0TCwp8Z0Hx2LcLet2smHcH/fv8/bbacdTEWsNvkFkd/2BngMKh8a9B9DbqCCnWSdDjhSlPxp7y9OYq7dlzYCrEM86D7junpOpbj7/jJKaimoK1PPBZU2HKoaIVvHUk@r4XE9gnkA8UVReM7Sd3JMsLWnHjo3K8OlBgVPPjA/eSfV4v7g5az0jvjivrkc22QnPWKeuI2mIUWp5PT5IimU9PYHzKonfDQLwN8uia6qbweHYIbeX3rE3bquZR8aAQ0/ttnMTetbI1JX7sqWp2ohsKydAwoeMFGSZf9JDjx/iiAcISrCJ5jgYt0p7p8SITh@pEHQiKio8JYu5X6Esb3EgQp2mEFj/N@Wl@iyJ7Eu3h/ZzXznr1q7PSV2EP513nD@8i2GGGn9Zf8xg5q@8p7und4qxsTnmNX09vY5vextfpFSXdMF/TTCJxtQevv67oiGeDAQA3ZES@TYbffgb4DTk7pKyj8SBiK8N3k9gXDB6GP6Q0A6AZGzwognz413cG3K0Jb7/H/683oJO98L3NR4zZxhL0zaSAth@ZohnklASFFzwAXvKi7nlb3Fq0899Zlj3RITM8P@0iiktBD2fomJomKMZ6g9VB/A2ZR7eFN3JPfBnSVuIemvSZnx6H32@i/FNfkLml0PfYkP4tvE6N6wLXJ/rq@yqOio4oPdU6fdoT8rM7phh5EoUAHb8jMpx/5vW@L1YWiLSWHrIZRygsvc8/snD3WjXjImja2gNRddCgB@ThenKkgbbUltbTa7L1hgpbj1rjj9WSFXyo75sMAT5Y7x9g/ZtivV9Tn3XPukrfMSKsYYO7VcYHVByM@IjI2zb8dSz6dk3JKsM6U9pp5R3r5L0Wl77W4ltS4cikZZV8n0h@S@i@W@a2RM1CtlFhuV83hLzBnONkmec92xitmK@2mKq80QkYhy2mKu@MKk97FOo6J9F0Jh50mrbsCy8lQbAE1xlc23BFhDAHfbIEyqkb2rXOkhdJmXDaltVix9zzaItucdG7vY@4BUU5YVzIfVmXyb9bJv@mTH6nzHUP2C1yC4jid4q0WwGb52tNIAui@Y52xiScucPla2obPorK6bj3@sUtuY8lP@2euY9BIbsF93HBA0rZ3Xcf50nAcB83SGDsPr6CwKZvuX9xHzvdAgF0uCWBzxhvq3C8593HOY/3hSLvJXLKDbqP120KMJ@sW8KRF2t5tWfv@qvrVVVB8FtGpZ9GiTHgomK17h/95BuCfwJqn1gDiR/TdPiIAOMEZGfQ2BoxrHJg2AiSF5949g0fx87SlL2@sVlDgXRfemtRBaVkSvSR@8C9q4wswjCVLD7CFQhEvXm8nyKafTMz@xY5dukgoaSRd8sn3AsSe6DvIen3ALy9iCNv8jvttYvCasDvoxMzv0fnG3Kc4ghF6Azg3UMWMvVn91cqhW29S4vd@tst9HaNABsx4IBYrUTQbul0sOHQNiWFaaq2KyQkFXf7pO08@LE7JUrvq2xEK9g9851kEm3XDBXDduf3fq06W/mQtB0VhIn3oUerl63HBaKLMWmj67YsVavzAQlbOqdPHu8VUGzzdpDAWerGT8aK94YhJ69VJNFcu2oSMgfxgYspZ1qlb/Zl8DGMXzd9dXKCCQ40IoKtnOtSLP2q/gr7XbXsd8egdpjwqoB9hvX@ofStef3VUfYV5fKm2LcNiIl@Ou/daxytS9iwHGYHW5b512TtjYmPJ99bRr5V6Br7K2vfYdt6TvANvr2eW1i40ErQZ7uRY1yYHYffZ9Rbi0SeBR2jJYgl2Xisiq8p3VTt67RaFd/XxJiCYzRcfnUD67sNvN14iI9UQH/FcquX48t5yD7Fum/jmvrWzoW166Cil9j6XJ6tSFD3xH9t7aIFEdWner5aKXdh0E0kEt63WxHYayHvZhynvrpNsJ62hP14vAF5vx/6TgxV3fz4oLjeupSRCDAGOLJvY4mf3ce9ti7b0uev@i7ks2C3OGrjGm@6AbejldDU4XDIlmy@msAQwfQccTYSx7wFfvvJbA13jVA6cEPn6YkMX09P6Jzz9GSPYtg0622kPxzYb/cIb72k72DXm@mdV5/iAsB0Yr0izl6As58OtvxQDvB1jOsXp65zTRVTcpwdcH0It6jWnhGeCOu13uLoxFgvWwRJ9YSjOIUNx/D5NSsXQuPCJ3GttMv5aBk6eKifoamK/TbGsfXGTnLEoOEsvRKyp8qcI24gVinksbstiiyHLGdfjLxgjZySab3NjlOsJWSHN35aGATJjk84BVOOsaRZp9@sXT8ML8lECCY@WsDjnixM8CVnILt7VpOvJWiVYVEaDECQGPvEUcvBpYnvPQuoYiC3eRltm7yqzj4kzfYJI2cR2uvAwE7PzmP5Bh2OgzWV8gNnN19gLLrJ0PjofYg4aREo@CbgkrCCSf9W3o@epXf3yjofL@L76HnClv3FGimgdWQQeWWLz@Tzy/bStL1pSfTA1s6lc8IEZZ8Ikib7lEH0UdM8rgOXc@4GBi23CU7mnQfWPXhUwjH1QSGKBz3AaN7yrQEDV0GjjWyvedcuqQr9Ax0Jk/cgQXnESiXFAg5rZ28HO6RBViTW8u6zFYzrh77rB9xMpD4coC60ZA3zO6KMYXJc2EaW6Y82OmtDBbuy1QWcm9jWTQSmGh/2FPzR4/IBFp/L69rBBPD27scHS/O@zQpK0fsHptmPd4pqJpNpTli9fp4ZZIaZehfus6GyrzOKFhimcCH3M/lSb3muJpozMRxqdm@yvYivlugvNOlikrvQCpQU7U58d5FF6iK6iuUiuQwfuhXPy2I0kbsVbw0hIwspZjYa3/SFutZjdUO6qlxX6ium2LppD25G4l2nM0ooDUqr32UHNwvhJtlRZu1WqmTcCO1cxRxXRuaUXVYTnXhrrhjZdjM7vFyW5uNFKa52pVjuRki0Re1izi9jGn/Rou5mzWG8cbEcp9hJf5nJGf1uwudjurnsIHnB9@/Ey0buqj/QY73YuJHiIrPJpagth1cXynN5lGvMeJ82KpbiM0qplWZzIdoZ9@QL5a7ebvfy2dp8zBp3Wn8U7VxPzV5Sj0ci04wwHEVjpampJ8vZzFXCzGdK7aJ82zbvlu1kjTIvzGaidcmnZN@savKRab7FGKH24lK6aszjF@GmeqFcyqVRbXw@Pa/J2nScj0rV5iSqD26LPTUcvrhpzC66ZUqPXna6yfoonMzzC565iqnqJNJMVcr69WKafa4KnRzfyAq9eCgbuy2wo@vqkq/OyvV6p6Z1WpOEccXKd8XQiKre8o1MdlwsT5Jss7IsJc9LjWkuV1rMemFxoGam/U7k@jY@L1eEUueGiVxwU/PaJ@WqMjO6vDSW7dZV6bZi3EG3vr6UouJykW1ndfE5nzOu62Wmoo@HjehI6WvthJRT@ctaKWqWxpmLeecuVcqOBbHWG6vjZkfuTE0pP2KK1DI3vmn1hHlRWs25QrTcvmFGhTpvJjKDSIMZiWJvLFeN1eC8vBo0pr1BP1U9D@WF56t@th2rFzT2umhEK8qS6jazorSq34jsuJa6KN31ChnpWonlaoJWO7@YLcLhriTW5rEVu7gdFaPSgo@GytXs7bXv5jJc95V92WxNjVQHVDhfPO8MYlc@tSismLLIPSdyPn06jS7yU3xTXrmlyPokJoeSxaZvmDD0Tur6et4zSrf1XIeXV8m76/E4flenbmclQ9XDyctiJsXUxiH9nBtVSncJSSlG59lzuZAqdVatpFkoT@XkRXmQv6zr@eaEv00VBo3lcjxIXgq18jhDCcl8vT7qDdq9Rbdh1Jah6yg/6vkK54XK8wD6cbtRDF@2svHBtB5pX@WVWa1Z9K3U205Zy1XGbKGWnMabiciEmi0uk5mGqUha/vw6Fb@ZSuVCJj9o5VhVEG6f@St2zDWay1DSSOg3xdsbzfCZzZ4a7Q2zkeXNdZdp3xlG7EKi7hadeCkz1vmr/sK8NBJNJaxWb0LsjVhpybFZR3ru1tRRZsJctW5XTG@@Ki5qJm82xmqsn4iNzxfGs7660q@oZHfEya1KTi2P@PhVV1olmBirNLs58ZrvXoZDmdbg4looXswGq5YwCY8unqcXPMcbtUy3dy7HZwvNJ0aSszLVrHRuB4nn51BPqHRTUmbcqtdKZrjJMdNuoxx7LncNo8i3SlI2KinTfLZ7Pp7k7pZc01isps14TxaXNT0cKlCLSve6zY/UgVE07vjR6rZ4p1xPw/Hb6khMmP0xO5HYclsMJSpa3Zf31eTz3mAZb0@FGQ@WoXZT0thsZjSqUlV2kphllynDVM6Nq0ovd5mRMplyMnyjhRMX49z5xaIvtVvtykWfU6N3vVwkXu0NQuF@tlIY1KKTQaJWSUTLOarZW97U2X4@KbFDTs6NLpdRLVUOZ@NMe16/uBk1h0pFzmU6CzEb4ZvqPNHhRKUlrOIJ5jrkGw1Tl0omFK3FqZaZN1vl4jziU65K1@Hacsnf9rhphBOfu4aP766Gq2pb4FR5WH6us832tJyTRqN2PMs3Q9VsIzRdGXNOK9eoVL6msPnyYlacDxudkKHlL7Rkb1Hp52o1oaf1I5rYq2YWYmjW6dzd3LSqyuT2ZnJRT/Sqqz43irVNsR6vLkzqGUye9qzcKvYWedEQR/XZs3K@mN62mWjrfFJu9We@UequO4tIt9VQuZJti9y0dDNImK3KQru@lEWZmYSrA4aat2qrlSlk1EJlft1diO3VKiNljWd2ccVw5fNS/tb0pQrFTL7abHC6XK2el/MZbjK/npdvEz5h1bjux6Tx8x1VUxQ5rN815EQ2FDHCrVh@leNH56HpeXbSvGymWI1tXbSvr6/YocxP@ES3mo93rvlOJnN5tbwUuXatptWuWk2q6lNu7@6aTLUpl1NiuVRvqrHSTL/udBLcXM3ccKFSdNKblxfZ@fV02pmkLn1dU@Ai6koQ2PpcLjPCBchOkhKms1quUjOW4efV6Hkwy6u37VRGO49nckuxPxNmq1AmP/MxRnEx78clLRludhfnYpe/Hgyu6tlhRJtpzXguRl2mxGul3csNr1NL4eqi3C5OTaHR70UlnxHSRs2bTMto8UvpnI8PZy2jK0PnE7VYM5tLGfJdPnmlS75Qks9SfOeaqzHlYey2ctlX57nFdXuZhylHkhVroZi6VNrT5Fi5uDKyV53nq2Ry0OpdjKHg6fBuyEstX7bfE25EuULd3V61x4XatM2Mbm6vE7XWhS@5iujnz7w6POdSy@aqGgoJYmowK00XEa3MJ8@TV1VevlxU6i1RGMQb4Rv5XFlReSUxDGVEdj6bK4xvGcsmCwMx26ooer7FXyQEtcYxzKJzZ1Y7t8mr8HnoJtSYzENh43rOhMSuIi27lW433KeyM@NK6zTYWcF3YWa6jVGdP5eZSqdeWqnLciFstDKVnHg1nS@18lLSI3d8@Twn13iJBbMkFh809dZ4lZ31qI64KOeyycRd@AIkyDDk1Lwb5QTe0AaLEVO@nl7Ii9F03NZ9kwVT9911F7HUsD00GL5cblZK84IeUy@NkULF43z4oqNrCaP@PFmWcmZ@2G7J0VyqPehVL7rMdVO8St3kGncJIVZjSs9CqtOIh/hyrMMzbF2dzEwYkfjBmCovQ32dlwWdS0yrz7HCdOrrL2dT06fdJc6vkp3BOMfOeM4XyfTUZ27RvpRDUiUhDIxqZz67LXbAQlTas5ZCFe9aWuRKuhAbF@3q9ZitZeork8mmOvxtdNDVWVERZ/WIGbssCYMEL@YLd@NR/qL0XAp1xefQnJX1m5tI8YKlEqIva6p9mWnfaDfKKswJmW41eT3vr3KTYUUULkrhvN6tx/uNK04uwDAqPZdDWrt4Xr7r9@QhI6pKtVEPhai7eLjQua0/s7P@TW3VVBcX@uAyU5Mjt2JJUWu3bTZ/ozOVRLZ4kxvV73LLZLymyz2hOUg2lYnvPKLyXEYpx6mEMBOy7Q7TEqQIm1isetxYYNi7znicvGBWcWPFZBRjPkoOVqne@YTt3FXU8@ZyzJxPFne17C07FXwsW@M16sZc1WLn5x3f1fK8VRrIrZLIM9xkOTIuslPhct67iWd8SS3U9BX67eGiXBtonQKT6PWSbCMS6UTN535tadxUqHa@fBFJ5JfmQiyMp5VF8kLLxBvLResmGh3fjRbVZCNejy3YmTouZLXiIMaot0ZCWTQvBsWsUBCvReN61eMnVHw1rZSKyYIvJnDdWvcuJBaY50ZfNocDsXl1G2nEGT52Ua3N7@7yGWaSEEeFknwOY@Kcu14sG6PuuHdTNSISpVa7vlJ8FV817m4qfaXWubwe9uaDRKKmX7RHqemqq9Wluk9btUo99Txfm8j51S0IXLyeio1acqHVkW7z9VCVMuOdzBxscDZblpYDphQLXYlK6HIxOU/dTjrxcXfczs3q3cV4FG8kYupUWCXMznNsKrQS3ctJg@F73fnQFz6n1MZqeVu4ierlylwrmzVVuAolw@W7cWtSmLZ8k9xVsWfmOiGtF@6U51NfLgZWQfK6nQpXelejbGl8fmNc3IRTVLMoLafJ0Xn83FeDwWQ6MqrJthyWZ0yHkdvzmTCehLhKnmvri16rWO5X@uEko/mkxNy8ij9fdmt3nKlFFYYylvH@nPNdFMCCyEvdWMPXNrXQBOYiodtZ5EoZRMKGctto8GZOTYxbkZQQLeptRW0v1FE7LN2cJ8ZzXroaUVlh1Y/KrXqnX1ms5v3UONrnGrNWpnirdCI5RRsuDJ2Np67Cbe65NtEjVVOrlVt8VrmZcJw49y3kbP5ab8yo/qCS6XeKz1Nx1o5WM9HM8rYfik7vZiNWWd0WuuFRrZcZivN6J7qqzyPZ/jmr1CeSNtHDTKjZVgrj5KJ1IVxRl6uCsBwmb7K1drR1NUqNI/Jg3KiFluOqJPJ3d8aULXUH5Ru2X4q1szep8YVoZIREKyVejphFpVe9i@f6QjRE@YalCRPOlfnIZeHWZ17ycuxZWrEVc5USlWWlJfUag1lGK/dHrWkle8Fk2fDsfFGdRC7qTGTKZSfJ/JXe1WVKKMQyi1b1Om4M7zJmO6rWwrOkdleTBrfhfm3I8ZNQPAk6@Lrfu1u2MvXsvNytXDSMjDJYCT59fqWcl4rFrEJdiJ3Ks/HMqeI0E21Vy92b55uMPmjGeqZRYhfPArNcKtXLHM8vu5mSMa60LxtKKRGa9LPXiZthv6y01JoUuaL4VGJ8m2CUBn85DQnRWiZafG6f88@lWbyujhWTbxbuWLNSB2VXirWqWnc@WeWGIXERiRZujeqgr91Bbx2tqPD0ot7t18WRspjXL832VWTSYMftuTyOK5zmixZS1SrHDiI4CYvdqspEla8G5m2jMrvSGWa4ik8F7Vy4kqhyWBtkSvX4ZZg7P@/mUy128lwWwsnr6DQzD1fr1z4lJmj50mAih3Lj@ki4kWDK0InXRpehRkVqDe6mudvUskGtuj0xpVx25upVbjzPj2ejZmsRgelVs102jEb91uyXZuHeZULuVYf9Zr6Yu@FzHGckqkquUB1r03ZvMr@IxqhRMXI7uk5cSoP4OFESlt2rqZaqXa5KueFF1NdVLpNmlzPl56o8eq70TLP3nJDajZtLppNN8EroeZkwb4cdxqAukpPCeVRIrEpDNtFSJrPptF@tK2ppWbu5BjYnwpHmeY/JaJ2bmtnuXwj87UULLP1LVSg1bi@1xvntRX/aVyg5AuKbY/Sr87JRvM2P79h5qb7sSaxvXL2aV2OJmJjq@WaxSWU4zcdincTksjIr5jU9vrgGrT@oLWtloV65ptjJdbcw9l2KLJvUr1ftWbSeEW7jveu5OI/G8pmFMkwmW6HFzeU5f5PsaaX5pHXJDm6Y@V1qbEy4FlfP8KpYpbLPWmSZX5iFUKxwFb@4vRFG8Xm/MA2XMvNGpxQ3UxWx04k@z@vzsVApsmJzMZuHa8XqjalEY4v2zd34ClohRvGDxU0hIVxHhX5IWt3l9KLaU1pcJsRcMuF5q33jUwfKc0XwjWvhYkSLF0KLGgcz47vs9LIf77VGcuc8e5EaUv0oX/A1jXjpLv58@3wt6bcjX2ICKicp1mc312CS9MxWM7q4EVNddtXOJTtcr7hiC1dMJnpxMU2VwuHLcqrcpYxGbALS8jwP317m5fBNrd2MTn35Sn7RHzbuWvXc/Dp512UntU5jdomTsQgTmovVUb21rBQXLUmIF8b1gpilfKWbuVFNaWI93y7oTK0vFqOj8cV58VyYXvHTRUHxhQal1nL2PJ0IyctrmRN0pVg3hxk@0k2OIwu@pGWer9rU8oIrXLK5ZDupjyX@clRpGSNj1tFEKRN9ji18Zn1Uk65i@XrzVhm1hpWKzueuwwlDyI8bk/hda7TozYRC/5ISzdSMlxfnlbipZJdF6bZ1fXPZb4SWfC15WSnqi1CPKT43QjOTaSUbteagV9Gl8ggGTl@3papJGVSKOVRvKE4blkLzduaqnxwYufNQsny5qLakii90U6iP8mFjpvuY4aQazq/UwmVEnCcG9ZurSUjPzfpD31UtwdyNsuq8QsXMfqTDGeNUXWS73TajFeorw7hOtnq@qxuZEerhu0T2YsU2exGtPx12k93J@ey5271@7rUbF9Cctz4h3rh@pgY3VxdGQkzxbL@VzZUz6kwLXeqTuhidlNVuK9wVfd1FvjR/Dl@FiqNSj61UhqtVlr/UO0oyP@ld57jlqJVsU5FCNdS/iwjaZSv/3C0OpyM@V17wkVv1wvDdRiuL6bmeTMTZaGrGGZH2ZNL2JTOy5EtEhsthOFuYxfNMX693qELVl@uoKvSC@l2cqzBGtF@RTaOVaDYKqXqumLsoXxVuxXKqUeJub33dm1KukGnGL6@G4@hVlzWyTPZ6OGqEqVE5N@4zppmcSg2paBTO9fxieDe@mUx788SsbHRXyhU3lQYTVuS0caesJOKZm/ZzrBqKFK6Zwt1KVsKJ2CJF9Xmxf8nI9fFtJykVLpiuPIQJdB7kf3x7PdV5UTeGqQ7U/HqlJHKt6qCtX8jDGlAo96YaL05S0ngoRO6oOtNIFhMd@Urkq936JNHtSbfNy0hCnC5g/trNr67EPAOt3uo2htPQbbwApms0@lzqDCc3s0rbqMfy7Wa5FqXaz/W8yJYK5XL7zuyzlWpoUJyZrUTyosDyk@y4Ulhme9nSvMi3Ohe@kS/c7POzYjsjF9p9zlgs70KpkJ4RR1R8FL/OinnWnMfaoh7NXQ6rEU4uqYvqZVKb1GuX4exl4UZUx3ooe5NxPvH2MjWRYsuBmMmct0vd3IDK3OTyo3BbNPi64puXCFi2KHN/@NVHhQi6rhAwaqZKfZq8ptQ@5uLkKwdPkJMn8PH2nXMn0Nln@yAB0X6@GmiBcvyuFj4hfGwVQvY2g3hANW4tnrzeWwywznEC5ILneNBH5FBqcWcj1KVj5jUZHyXlawSQHU@yg4L7YOTx5B@MY/gCDX4HJbCJPFHnIbzxfpM2whE854PFc7UeT7a2PD3sNjVIIDQZp4jAT7/rBzxV4UfISLaAC9Wid9@2fuhkJz8QZ2gKOWnEFQi6SFb7VAzEtIvCak2MX5/NQJEDWZyNta@8coNj2GQoniLne9CK3/RP7lOP/iM@7aIFU@KUiTHV5/3xQB3ORFqmtVFvwS9XzzQdi9IRKCv8I@3DMtl4miFHKibgN0mnQvaRTOTziRwNi@dSkSPh8GRfN00H1sc6faS9JODHn2PXyRsppY8mjhRah3xM7uOPaSUdOpncK48nis/nNX1p08f6PBjxI@s90aa2J@K9@Uie2meO6Gvn0Xo8kBp9f1WRrqkKP1TdBk1eIrj9zAk5fcvpQBNO2@5PM4E3VX07RkR54iY7HfFtFO4Sc69ySqoDZy41Abfu1qcSyPh2Vfz5MI1HT96mYw0/fMAjNE5s34ntCnyhtGlPlvhj6gPhJ26B4@P0x8f2oTA8nmqGG2gYJ1mRFi20ZHgw@cRJ5VVtaWeWLJAnpy6nWyjPPLi36vV/D6QD1QOZfMLXh@gAZoFY7N0BpwE12Rr1WlRhuCwo631QPMfHe4KnnNAfnTTnxB@ER7kh5@48mbRETumByyltg5IzMGivfeIEib2X8KE34kpw5raSPoymE43sPwctem2O4LvcnjRO0tc5g8YUX0PvoVlkhuQQjS2AgRc8A23GmcJ20zhtgY5v5OErrA/iq5ED7oFgntP1JepGfPgA8fVVkueD9bJAD22qlmOlRYadl1TDazc1MA4PPHVr7mOa@MGdQBTZEj3ZSh1BKtb1neQJJE84c/hO8hBxT433knVIxlcIvpMsQbL1TOT@dBXSrZ3@dwBM9PIEcX0y1SeTk2SPdaAHHgXyYilsD@3zOYxdiwBtNYzVHrv5aftoFPqj1TqWsO2IF/RPIlYWAIq0x@48eL@RFpKK58F6LLnYKtPiCf2F/mZhtnMksPiJlARqF8v3Hu3gp7cIgP4HqpR@m@4UbrX2uqI78hOEYWeArQ3MitC//PI1ymxB3JU/9tGRPquF0A93q4YWtzZ4rFeMbdrVyrSyM@3PYx8ds63dHB@JTT2cThneqBCrb236tSgpfSgDEH/cjkaXJy/9aRNzbzzSx2vtseGj1S2@zcfwG@lBjyjSI/10bxPkv5@rHMo95ORgRO5tlAWeE8advGGnsYYO7EKfAfSam6/kjN@RGbuX/trKfl9tDoA@0qkJb04sRcuDaXhmE7iHPM5q122dYCE7dB9b8fh@M2kXmfQOMus8vSdAYJ4CDTiyOWrcGRMlJWg9kwp6PhSO@omLuQXysmGTo6y@h0//DJ0LGWcP2VN85cuuSqL3sOYN@LreyK@z113uVfUsTb@/cvfWQ83uT26kkX4rT0TqPsEoeUyH6PXBTSf0y7f10D@OM182zbdj7xie93WF0@iOJH6PCL68w@hvCtluFcKP9A7Hp@SF3to3hyRyCOH@QWnjWv/kxDhul1bfftcCQ6pOdtORZguhkwCG8nYuv21znW1Up3364pPpGDf@jRVG3iFPpAJM9hNqW53jdK5IBu/t2PXRUYQj2yn4JDtamLpDmSQ6ti2YwU6@IP@EzWwxGfkJfXqgqn2PYzDZBgPB4JzQAUB@6zirtVllmZeb4qE42@ilB/YpH864ewIxH@0oMq5ABBqftmwiEUcD0m1OsNts2TeSQV4ESNJxNIKinKcP0FnR0j708et4hF6bQB/2ZnI0Pp5JRk6utPU8GYl31IMrxynoGIrNYU2tT10Yv24IhDmDifbmfEvSBi97VhmsMzzt0y2/bE9dpBMpiDbxutEdL0jvyZqa01MXFrMW@Jc/HHxkpobO9CSFEZQZje9tpw5oQbHef3OMr38OJNFRGN/ebGsT4pdNnBBBTKClsLSgIsw99hue8RRRl5eyzqQjTosshQf3Er9xWZj1weq3TmzRVGNBfpcwWQgFp5qpkhS7IHJ2Hf2L9MvmPNUQeYrInjHY5JwSPBsYDz5fYMUuLV/JAGsZSCyeSuzdQnGPOYnCdT24XNh@SKjtT3r/SBlBgeOHSATK3i/WdAqai0jyC2U4TY9nrSEr8OEVCMrWKRMa8R3FIoh1YizJPVQf71kMWDHExRXl3p6nUMQhGFNkVdVQyNEVFPOfAgMsxn9oNPOFej1ov//A8lhHL3fLjxkfESQH1tlvZ7fdeNFbHY8LtBrlA1YWcVvlpTfIif4lPMJibTZhV5gjOy1e4XmEVg0CLLl7U401vNcCJywhjzvZdwbyMmSf6qGBHYW822TzbGULONkc4C1WfPgmNziex4MgroWJChTnBFkGoi1efNiwA4PIEad837p84x7LfFwTb6UH3qQHdtKDVrpF1AYqyA/1DdDxNpDr4MsG7oV2bcD8b8pK01DpUoWcLhVU9S26T74GawRhkiZtgM/WTWlJ5TrhdCchsJXy057Wt1I@7uRZC/g6/d5Kt@U7bLf8msod2M@75eOVshtIIGcw2I8svpLSoCLJn6zlx3UK0bA0HqtkZcf2JmJndUp7QcRWJwFQE/gWdey2Z@kNFh/raBzSZ1xnp59dQXtJ6pPnNRnWe3vedKw9fWSLS6RMH2HcgowkUA5J/riFguBEQaOdnnvmZF7amZdbaBHqo1Ms5ZwUutvBoWqvu3ga3bp/wR@ns@8S58Ad7E/8YFG@sCpvPWmxyyCidD@69rNpV5uY@lSwIu1KfWUU2ZS9fI1xv5KoqDgD5YeoKdZlCtbzIKI6Vfof13piW1E4muIN39cpNqc3AKwjvu81ISa@UP8/)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)

### Explanation

Well… I don’t know how this works. I kinda just took Tio’s hello world example, and hacked at it until it worked. The code is between the Emoji-gramming and Transcript.

```
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
```

Good luck Future @Chance.

Sincerely,

Past @Chance.

Edit: Updated code and link for correct version as @stasoid pointed out in #123

Comment: Where even is the Monkey's code?  Even if you don't know how it works it might be nice to know where it is when it breaks.

Comment: @WheatWizard It is that stuff under the emoji and above the TRANSCRIPT

Answer (score 7):

## 125. [Gammaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/gammaplex/index.html), 4631 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _       x _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00@O6O4/m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #0C8302",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #58007B",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002371 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4742 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaVpSeKkP97SpjgVFWgk6xIdpWtPVgc5NaHPImbRg8JwmGLQ6NbWpSavi/mwRmi5M1JEUwJwTSRkAmCnomi6YJD1K0y1F5ia9PvcqJfaqQE2HdIPOC/Ivk19MmlcnE07pGwAZp@l8NVsoZ15hSND0taobAuLhBcNQMTJJ04uCwL8CTQEop0tqOVM5f5XEhuhzIJ3TZGFBcz3D1DnelFTF4l1NV/tTHutlDgXIibwQJVkwKB5oPqM1uwWCGKAPaF3g@hYYJao6jVnoyVimJZrXNLonc8MgT8sSwBZDSVpA1tErSD@gDXUibJNm0Iog9GlDE3hJlHhSKi0sTEExgDojSEv8mJ5Lskz3BRkybEjh/YCMnhpbUVbBQaqvUjR8eO0V4eu7QwFgFMGpvKAB17DyKjIZOOHwYK5zmgZEAgMbQLgpTUBWJNNt0AJnSCiNkMUQlD7hm7aWU5XmlO1a0jOJozmgd6oT3IagI/ODBC89FHQBUHJrSfHMdckEFiBbM3RN4HS6qQuCd1dmd4qEwlQswcSKBEmznZ66C9WiG5rPyhHkNJM60CPNm0uKo4Np@vDpBL5pl@uEKlTy9JfDBwxbIgpNrOkezkunf0MbzMODAN8F22MG@gsFWCngikwzqmYyXEADAgMmEMhwGMRQYBYOavJWwfTpq7bYEioLqg@tQZcUuu0nNeOnuo7dcMNUbgyVllVlAPyEyupTBfmh0PEQNAGvQi/y08IMuKYqVhupc8Lh5lCCRjOwSbYE31ImhKGgTkD2bI465RqqPCVwkNMwUQCBK5AVMZZEuk2LnCRjFkhHVBbVumBMZRPzTJU@tjwoC6EfpB0yeLWPQBN1BsVxgJREQB@abPU8QhQAQ0OopKqY9Lt//e/6gwHgyfC8qvdtcW3TfZUnao8jxIIuoVFgVYWTCVkA58fSrexQwIyTpT5nYvHK0i6CEEFKnatTuU@rUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITc0pR@esKNLX0hWZILFZ9wPWhYUgApm1Q7QH/OQSvxAnVAZCYwmZpikg5oBdptMD95Ph17Pn18EIA4b9B7dMgwgxMQuOARiYI799ckp53Z0mSgXEzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkoUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhtPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA@wUtFhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK5/ZsQ5gABKFOS1zymDKDdBUUiALx/OCZtr6CmpimKCRXg87JDJgj6FBY0gdfn5dNhlL7NF1qwzU9Vbr2SMih0rGNpYCMuhUmrPNPbov6aCd5OXr0gFg9qpw188IskPAz653SHAMARAyYSHwUxOUGwjyfCjxQ5BdpE6x1KM1Fr0uHqK2SwcFHxDXRSMx7NmPYSrIrKOQjHdRBLBF3@KBMRZRne1EkMbfjvg6Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNshwQZA9m2lgPTXQcoPBxjGVSM9am3NrfgKDoatDNwVhGZqmZhyDbpfM4bQXhGZlmvqyZFYVbFnG1JeSqVrhnqz2QJca0JkYpwSGn/akxasakbg1w0cGNQOjSTToNIy2z1MQEY9bNEDLkfgcAm8luYi2JSisXxcAEqAgcMojGkR/FkEDNJYK73EFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLTp2gyqA7ZDBH6yyrg5oRQbXYiproaW7v8LRW2MQWc7uDI1VSPF/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75d7BvPA@YrMtcChZSZqHuz8@jjz6uXvWvobx6gW9BGoIoAN4ATxubzqNQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbpJV6r5wlMt07xIu5ipoTOy1GMUGAyfJtDdYMLh2pMfZg5OdgjWVdVMkwbDeAJdBCB7RkWZ6hQ6KEwWpIlklsgURVZQtDeN5qTmoFwLQWl7QiLq6mStXgxK4Icq7TqMuNCQ3pkE4phrp0YxdWpPAbfiExg/welbkKcGPE8HVOt2HWkDJhEQp3RBmEFRA58PIckUbx1pQ6YISpzmBfWeE/mFDb1g/HqOt6XEtzHuS38/E@HNnkmpXWgcS@yrPUFexKMBQRaD5mIVxG4ej1LWhQ7034PYk5darPZloEzos4GF@CqB0ymLwiYMFGWYF9BlySBz@O3mpNaC/UC5rI4X2R0CXJuU8MZe229kuraxECEEQRirqOY2oSewqGI7KGBu/DanKBlD8rMD@oaitykktzHpieRnD8CxbbiAFYSzaGTJJc7B0HZSVZhxzwnYRFVUixRglaRwTJ1cgjDe7aNnd1jZIaYniFOYlzE9ScHwN8ACqSSBFHs96T1Q4AuS7lz3gOnT3j62gXAN31ge9A7jzaluykLfvv63P@5DA7xtniG3hPkEP14HnoBv2FQB8d3WsrPiDfnZ37IEZjSVJY6wgYS@hZLncM7HyevAftSoSulAYMjp0LhLp3FBOPEHhsWvyJlFuS7I077gXPcXQli8a99YuRVpQmoEVzTWyPj3TvZX1pmVH@fMuqxyfYLFWsuQhE1rW@0iLLgBVI7Z0kigCb@DTseIojeLF2CAmFPrF9crvtWukobfr/VXGzIU43qsADM9rie9w0UkIv6eXFvdBQ2GgChzYyv4hMH9VbUqo0uDARhK9vU9MDBhYZahcbzAzMnlXRWjTA3NagoMfQWfLlu/74E4i6rrwHuAUE2Z/PwasSOCwEPfQFJxvTCwxSLpFVNlrrdEo2r46@UHCyTjKKiXNO/zhSI4pK4nmJuVSU17Pz/aACR/KrU/t7WISRDwqigKwrf6LIw70oSTA@H@VvBdFewYoZvQHtARN@PAPJU5AwTEtNkszKBZyM/XhBaHEn4qc/om9BWR3ZDjrCO8NxXd5NEkXpUlWzKdm/d04et5wQYNLk@Tn01WvHvL3z6Y4jhMB9ah/R1a5U2cDr4jR9@hnqyZGM51twQjqL7HO16d4/fd3jtUZ4L1u3/IWu2l6jvUT0AmkgHTu7fZ@/y3xBXXFcnPfi6O91Jl8vLe@GP6WlV1mIobdDgYQgNHIYvhMGDLsjXbbJaq78u0IcmqQTfI79d4ASa/YVi/@6V5m20SpwT4odXH1uH92fYSRYY3OkN@32lcTh6ocjw5YDj4eVcCprqIWt6@fq@GW2solv2mhlqbO6rC2td3VfsY/r8lHGSZU8cFha3gV6yoferMnoi@X0GYEeCS3v7KFUNJkjPIWPO09xpA54dzbulc/xGjx3vcdUYPbUmMZbDmMEMqCQFTtwzof0xp0a@X1v8@HfUGbeJbldhq3LEsgMYmv2@alA6H2F@Zgw2Fvl9jifJUmAp7NUi1NxJAbL6mO76fqJBdjUN7pYIB5uHO5xpqZU8Fv4tqHM/x7qsKh5Ml6OTftGb2qhoNLGwNp841CNQw8DbjQJlqO427xbv6VKl/nXNDzenZan@HSEz5tRop@W2baccMNwTy3a9AjnFPHya86gRsCOU72t9GShaBrN8dxCRmg3kk4fqS/lW8x/R65RHsV7BHoFWlsRHARarvUzzh92bqBDiVgrmYIphL/H2P2/sUaU9V5V/TOqBP@xKaaWB8ogvAt1rpmG4sJz2w3PjNsuh3tIAzTQRu4ZT43YatAUrzO3FG3q7qfWWU2lrj21vyuSqfnZ59o9Hr2HfZYDKY@Cqgs9zFOIF3uiBBlgpGvsf80RyblqyA4qqptU66cVU4eKVetCUwRuoHDH4oTARy@xWDnuuPpoZzeRdooeJ3T3KQIWuee9tUEsxv8LVhqopgfBWI1MtZPd1bTmnCDYTiN2Vns4SAu4O8Lu0E9y8mHFvCzkO2bygGa2KnKmNhaTjX/ebvkocmnE6@im1ft@VxpfKb/TTI7F0xfkOJvWpPXDLWu3aG3/YlgThJtz0HjLV7zkFJ4XWB7OE520T0Ae4sTicwazRVPUgTOI@H8/m8XsrKhBOPgQJgDhRxkMBdU8v3wqBhOmgSWEmk7@/pwy@L49Ax@0Knadexi358tLCS/bvCQiOeDXUr6/0h95g@dAcC7kP3g3JMh9wEVJDBDtwLyu3AiRK5WHRuqk4r3IRs1GLYqemJtRsM0zN0uBhySl8W6BYoNjJpVXVrT9PaOG/iOuV//fu@7YcyEKCSE8mAcX@goO@UOhGG6vyTVa5dekbTOPRjQRzzIS7EYemBXIY25pIJXZm4n8DssVVsJu3dbNurC25qKN1bVFiNijoVfSxMq9EsavqqYEmeXfA6l1MpmJ9PJwo9l/rm0AjCXEvhBbJbvt5igRCCKaauouT66RLdF3CdqI@EEUUiq@qY7AUhJf/17609fEiUUIQw7BRPXHi2SqRROZKNc55Xp0C1g2Ql6KoN4kEmg2RPcQiGfiNY8V6aH3LEuQAkMeBsrWMx1vZ6LtOgAwXajS5ouAd4Iomew0z9vH0fekz/hp4wwn/7Y8b7xeab64dAgjVcftoBOXlBudpODkHyJtVNuw4XLrta6OxEfHvWQmV7LHowTJrL2SqfED8pInfCnGyVE38IBTsuOiApBvQPuPUS1FanSR96ptaAEGiYdAz99EDZchCyPKuIywlu@2KWwwX9Cz1EWQnwNBsLwZ3FEBk9DSbprLPKH9neiGHyQm9KliVn4WA4kibVOXxKw2CJIV3oq@j4c//TwyIcCjwsEoVHxnCY8/Cw@CEUvgXuqTrk@pHBDlSo5L8cBs9Cv/xiwATM5Xpxn1gbU9DLD7/USrVCo5lpthrAzRersgdFVZ9wG02BsqDJMDUeqjLxqAK26JJgfFt7fCDqg/pgA3o89CFHn6KXJSgqErvWMTaHXQHXoRW00kFrb@fbZPywm@tNNkPYSnyVamsgUaJtbUnXiMDYsuE2tjWl35Eh5D906ymoZqfiuKW4R@MRVrjoNDAjAMygdiq6vnvNkE3KGtZqqE8kAlrLroMDsoc32zg@vEaxDwOwaQPxFgBZtC4Kq2ulW3XbW/eXf4YKazB6/SMqvFNjguOrNUaIr9UYAJ3YD1aOYqZUbtULu5lAmDZOsoUFDP6gbkXSgyx3O0u2VNu1y9E/MLwMLQcQTt5oUIOeSYbUkwUibSLqfxlUCHY6sgdhoA6hUV0F6YxsgL7u90EB9ZYm6i9Q3EGy62xtPQcU2nUAzAquh1M/7aIQ1ki/dfEB/TSHKQr/s5X5kMARzAa1xyXxQWB@96//neWG@GBC@E/tsAjhf2WFf2KQQW9dqSwa16xBtrRLNdqAQdGq@IRbbNUJxyUc9yRlKtDSBDg4IwxBcIvYTX03eDz3beAnNAIwExUs6lRSnqA/etC35phh0IwYqLIYJDuXwgLaAVQycbV5nqJbKAwDTDwWj7IMEBmYOQgDkoUwoFkIvd5jkDVqJmnpn3s8fXp6SrsMmKoK6fiJxUjmkPsp4vp5TeghwFKWxXFPQx7IsskBaWd2Ns8h52O9mBW7nJt1048nYExY7QLjkYcEAMSL0YrNDxcMeKrNKmh0RViYRGkvHUsKzBiFuFgIlnOwgygAiCzc6L34WnY3W2LoKLAlzcHtZnB1EKyBYMeufaJz/xP9YD4oj7YTKw0C8x/2CJIC4T/b49m6lp7MW59Kz2uPSKwN/bmhqLhJWgRqaU@YCUcYNu7d6ikuGxXQi/3iF0AJPQF6Fi9II1UzMrlC6bJaa7zxCSSQ7tdgbtp9dup7CAT994/rgPuV1DtMzRaZxnW26LBym6rNagNCbJYcXpO5r7TXlL5Tesfaj3xbNkl4UxAb@l7EZAoXKJJVubfYN6nMFmDO2i95U6rH@@Xl/vH07EE5eFP8L/vcpQ@CRyhcEHowiLO0m96jc0rOLmsTn2Exgo7DTti1eRhg7Y5k3W@i3/cUXD8Rs/EXdPZz0VswfMb0hRmjTGWZCr6z0wt1DzJWUcRVziLMoRd0jUMqi6RuCuSpN7tl29TQdl3ePrxje1itmVS1JqHEbZlTYP6hS7wFbRAFbU1ViY8tTFZK5mZ@A3MmXBMg07glmbKAqljvPvUlMjPmdMf1a53SECZSoOnQg4pj4/0Higy92oZQN1nqnXDp@wW99lf6mmNg0NBkyfSgR94iiFNBqI3HixVgT2UBHfpOU4@29yDtOPn5iJ9gbQr8qqkavZl@5wUnVIcZGJ2fAnIQA4G@nE4ATiSXuoCjhEBX1ABkBj66HSLuoRSPXYfgpB@D0oNDYdGXBjDSeLx@UEk/sOzGw5Dz@mDa7AY9bLHqHLfVthnzq7witzjG3XNBSekLCw@6qx8/Incg3j3vzNxe1xsZIK6Ztp9m/7WPpqMsONPutRv/xlcKIZVaK4LdvpNKBYcGhf5kMHuAEhumXoYgjKEeccJptGdKnFwNOkiTW8@DR/Ebpu6lA2c4ns1phfb5yLwDLiQhSJOcIglJMi4jefA5Dg@ThnbGWEPp42UlafQ9Gww@QpgU4qUPceUgB@YGzrm9FBickOWYoIUBGP6OkaI5zLCQIut6SIqlcNqvA9TeZNKRB0PSAYEXpNb02Y/0RhtseqDF1VTq2G6NXXWYokEsTvdoDEC7R805Fifw13YKAq6hEgOoHEwoJVAon68ERYH@6gGZmUDvpLkpCJnu9TsPD/o3z6eQEg4sEi9sLyMgdPe5lYL7i6yCPXPInJDZ68kLjPs/P@DAL9pD/5L5IybInHzxHMrpJQPGmPfMczhMs77Ikc93qBx5DhU0R378ESe9L4dg7TwFXUHXAoACh7L3BOQZrKP0oXJyyJ16Dvvp8BHJAbc@n/cLZPiNwQS/HHIvzOGPYE34IUa3eqfn0PBidwgFg@wL0Ic95JDxg8x88bhoF3n0D4s/lHw@pCF4@IQE/IZ5aPjIuPLQYMj8@sQ2cpnBxFEju7bKuiXePMpoMdCOPl5r9BjxFrXWm58c4O3HVvak7bOP/vCHAzYOk6hP8YhH/RSOfDw6oA8@u5gjl@768pCfnbjvOTEcfH6sjWu1W@@Dx32Qq7rYqAtq89MJfcRQB8xR6JcEw/z8889gfdL3Z8Gz4KP3PuB@vPcszhKJoxN/PHnk/@xn3f6TA1pmQyzr9YTDXoZ@aNAPCY478kXDn5UTSZI0o9@HrzrEh6jAEkujlHyAj4etud2xiLvxE/plf/r0Ef7IP3zWt/j7kcTY0QTk7eejl/Y8L6iDsw@L7/08wbeaJcE2w7LhB5yxReIfP3@AKgs@8jk@/kzmMbQrkXSp6mcEpocHLBuj1QMY@RYC3aMXiwB@qAN@sThYQSJ7sIQ/Fj/5g6eDBU0d/Cad9n3nZ7EOBYNPTog6@Pn05/Q/4UMdwDzj4Ozs8eXFF7gP/oTIH30B3@n96Wnw7GxxFng8u6cOvlAHixfqIOwCcXk4og7Si9M6oeA@f2bT8mzPjMsQPg083tfKYPw2/eHTwEG4mMn5w41W9oCFu9jmFhMjeFsvZPLVFkDXyoVMo3BeahdaNYg3Hp/OPn/2BYGPn4Nnj0DJ4gffmS9tmiZ993QUpL/6ebKvi3XISaAO8meLFhM4BWLLdkydFBN4gLsHLxT2C3Vwf3Dv@RT@FA7JoVmIHbPja7W6@a9WIV5ahEaqHhqGhmwfGnYRElqhZWi5CE3UKtuHoAB/oc/VeDXKTCBCComL0CCkhBSW3cH2/v@kql5XVUCoQjZzETIRd0iE66BavQZkIhQ/gj8pFEIqF6EZ/IdkImnsT08hb@jhgbqnXT8L0HODrDsYcgfjbrf0GItrz19ewvHnezKux1KP98JCMh9dtN/99HCfSqXcjycHjPHwwFjKzBWOuk4Q5OXl6SmfaWaenhhc5licHvo@@wKf4ZM@853al08H/TNkavD04wPl9sw7nQ5@O/PZ3AqRgBXXWSdu35AAfGbv5N0NLPaLgcdzH3v88uL1ej88uE/cVk08HloAa9XjYh8WYZEOu7zEjE3BGMBG0NKIx7xnZ/EY3MeT3oAnRJKtLA8uTdMeXEEyLQ4Sz4B0OqPr3JIARWEYenBx@tOD6z78mE6nYiQ6FkjFaVUPpCJel9f7E3t6apcR9kK0y71wqbqb/vKy/ef58nLqIR8v/nm9GGn/nnk9kOyNwd3ii2dx6jn1YBxEYa4vL2cYJHBfIHTv8T56X16sOPj1eE8tnGde4B3O/f8Z/1WDNjTaffBygOaDQkdjXk9vKXijcU/Sl7L/0h@hAh5XxB2BerncnPv@/vNR5CgRvf/0ePR45Dk9Ch49nD3uKGev@4AGWXZkL80eIN@og@BJ3cWGXW6UxRNcqldlISjD3D6SOtkVBveT5@j1J8mmfEe@z/dHqZRV9tHRLx9p2gvooDAXfA5AfmkPfXp2uhaqDUrvGXy/0DaTIfzyBeTMSgNrxGMvxj88LEIhAk@f9NKHXw64lxOCn35xuU925JXg97hPyG6N64vrkNPv2UfXi@vwS@8FzbYj1kusg1j05OQoaoUTyRMYpdkjOyUEKV5rYTMGKYLB8aTnnhygOLmB516oVbonDCQY4bQdJvlisRgTht/FD/FCeEGd4K6GtYXiCrisDkQnUwTfAW0YKQpmBj1o@TmdCMH4J8ucTqui@NGKhykO3RMEsDIFWcaFOpwBgCEs9@cw6/xIHYCiAfvXEOAzqXHCVBDm0@lcWH9yknHMjWjPCGaw@Pn9b//qX8D37@H759b1z/@PVAx/f//b//l/@93f/C1E/hf4/t/w/c@//@2//WPrS@7/Ab7/z1bcP9jfLTjrSwGu/@H3v/2Lv/v9b//VX8P3f7W/f/36@7u//E/W//9r/2Hwb3/3l/@AP9YN4PqrP/vdv/0TIPEvMfwvIQz/dvSf2sGtWCv4p04Q8v37V8B/9vvf/pu/s8N/sg2yFQ9Z/xTi/2Yr/k@pBN2qwU@9dH7R3Lo2C5ncBRWns9VK/tUlZgPF6HKh2FzfJqxUJ2tsjaJbKJdf39oXqqtOaZ5DURBojrYUJgcjNJ7lEKRPqbNGoQnRzSqdTK7vF3gfCZP7WgvvSxV6SW5v8VqrtQ2XS6VQTD/SsYTfHwwG4QevfvIh1@DhTw4I@77pcEBd4ypoirW2niXMASFdSOFmG0j3XCF7nT18nHiqvR8JF4zCoC4NhjD3mqtrAMMwYFxbj3NvRr0OdQG9aYLP5OHD2yaa3zAtD1FB7HvhcCoZS6Yi4aQ/mUpGY2w8FvOzYT@bSCZSIT8Y3kk2noylWH8ymopEo9GUn2bDsVQCpmlKXxIZBow41uWiSUBSeHxo5RSf/lGDwzPqoC@IMPf9QC88fe@Hg74TQU@TtCuSfAjRLoaB2f2Q048W94/pL65whE5ACTRLu/yUa0Xz9EEol4yEwnjbw9tsMpGJR/D2iaTCJxfC2z7eJkLJYjaBtwLexpKhUCKLtyLeFou5ULGIt1XrFj94u3RuQ4DKxcNdT@b4MYQHEB7ooHQgvCDxUwGCKgTRT0UxOYKdF5ZvPysrqfddSdVltV/tVeFjJQ0GTsqguv5YSXs/JEkUVYCy5h8qXp@qC/XJTqo6Sda1WuWfnlwvJ9gCKAv00uP9Quw3D21IKwFk1RPyT8FoiX2aJl3xhOv4CK6uT64IBBceOuSGYcjlfnC5vPepx0@uRMx1DHOtgPtH9hPMaFKuY1ci4aK9J64wCFLM5YrT4YTLdQeaWxgE3PQn14kumFNdocMnL0jBKh06IZTQzx68cn787Xm/2GC9kxdczAEynz0rn88PX@8npBisLzAovcdLGO@8Jy8gjI6Ur8WUBvMxGKThC1MpTNfSViU9rpSHJuNG6sFlD6vWhNvjdifCbrfXfQJIPtKurb7tPSGE0BbDPE6tXVBPqHUKrEC7ap5UAGwUOpACsiyS/rstmvTxsWFyOi7BkCKPaVc85cJoADlNWWWdxXpHx3424P9MWQNmnKUOXqg@PnQRTdEnqROcV4Eld3pmU3dFLxMD38UWvSfUoRspdkd2bNsD8ntI0zBHCUTUqHpweHgIU7nmmSviqgafThl7UnbGkNnYw9mJLx3N@cgMJ@jM@c5wBvvmE41SuoA7@n081MaylZMx5MuANg4A3YnvH/MJQrlpQEqdoDnlOtAsg26JM2j6waL19DcHxJima1@cvdepQpaHj6@x2bjjBnm07f6R9v6mIslfkpHAGVlMQemhoaFeGqmfEj8lf7puVVvV4ufQcfI4@fDwdmL4GZShVC9QB8YvXjXG/ka5PDk41tyRqDsCs7/0gVVtNuE9OAsngga3PHi0HZM80QSKGtwT0yrMHoid3c9852Y2IRNkKCn5R/3BQAr/0fXPvxwyjNtN0@xh/DeBU@v/FH5yVasIVzzm8qLDlvHT009PBzQYSLQrHENB9jG0ZQJtG2yexZFC/oQjg/wJwibCgFvnDtMF7xHDMO0wDCGpVDwZP6D@wDBf2wOB1PWioCgIujGd7FsVzOjSNYcrpsp6ZRAC19OVoMPVOWHGGWtoHGxw2RtHm@04ewDaiiIHM@3GLQ0G3akwlqIwJJETvWgRVYMH7X@T7KDTR3gsFrqReakv1AfANeVN4okFPycU9QG9B/DW48D56R8N04s7qyEv9eGDrcAMM2iYT4gcM9mRAfaEeqGQPVy/b9C4YEs2Si3fMw734lXNcu2Vl7SVySAa2ho4idsYlrtF8BEtWlRAbY5oUiKhHCtnFf/BAutNRSSlWCoXIA@dpkWy8G/nduk9PFOBVO@j6LULp0MQhVgQnHCKgCMgoINID8HtnaCDG@8hkD6axXSRbCAAFJgRfkKJnxbtjPd4@wjZEb3Iy6oBiK3SPVYN6KMnu1i7Ds64gJUAFmLtiF4mg4c@4P126@HDrvePXvqL41/jwVT6lA571@4ZNi5oDOvsMpKRn/QtwSGHVdhsJtjYRz807YnlqOFZw9kxG0a9UEemf3JiNZV2Ql15eO8XXGA@@c3kxx/5n7T7yeOJd5I28erzTWCYGHskC@TITE/SIB7avfR4Yt77fNJjeuK98uA9jEAwWr5QosVsw2vXDWqupIEW3IQyvP7VvRL4jfLoL94rPiB56j@6S6/8XDrkX8BXSrN@2f@cZu16QJlmeuVTTrhT@OJa944jDQyZPu5kJwqzjD1yenXPPaaBHzJk9PmKUBmg07iXfb5HLxQuQ@LbjCfyjz9yPvlscSIHAl6E@inyqXhvQuDRl8b7Yw93uvi0up9C/mMPXNNQjOwF4iGfzeuXNe1A3wnw2GrTDekWjQskbwHkTdLpo7tPR3dH6Y8fV/eLwOTRb7H/OLSRBiR@gcSfbDkZeY7uvPQrlpA5ucf1g3T8Q/DIAKtVAsPk6M6vbeW0KDy6gxQNxj2b6hfUl@RIJWcfBSXMdoyxDsEgj9GTqQ05@ckgp92ZfXQEhLwZg5ckG9zy4NQkmCNw6IDth0m0EuAIBKbZR7xh4sPi0yfKKdr22oCSUbn0cC4Fcw1ywo@OCwTkuEDLpfpb@nWfGnZ07trwb5TuCjRMMiLxre5KVBPpcIbO3yMIqoEvoZcTS2NZvjqgbIj2ABiiPRAugFoEmWTrCRsybSdCazkNBLlQT4iW3zeewmCgfgL1tun5oEIsMqAz7yFD8o/SRDeBPEkQoqVTUh4EoKtQH6ASSAPWQXqkz0CR0T/@SNu3p2mY1iRwLEAwhBv5WAR6QykU/h2UAg6kcgQyivqQFAK0fcAU9DDbKSj6TyvIdgP1QAbfyG95gwaJN6hnqhiWEzTyzWuRgW3x4cMILEWbIPgnZjLkh7SXPxzYw/0xnatewzy8UL/ONOAXjPjk5hS54/V5Y28OLtLwQKKepBB/Kp6rs0L3kgf7BYw@ECm1j6cJ9unLVhkmuJW8H59tA9YfWIsFMKAerzEJBjkxxAiq@oCZS2OJ2T1nFE9@I65b5FTTgHMMHJJDBmd545q98cw2cJ4Pg7n9QM7OQZQTwTDs85gCznmU5MxN4qQ@QV9r6IX2@U1kV9zZ2CPbyLg25ifOCbo0kMghg0MLwU5@ctSOaWUn/YPCc5f6nMmhRFMpmBYf0yE/BlgnEHYCEScQdQIxJxB3AgknkHQCKTvAOphZCzMbTkYi8U0wsQkmN8HUOhgNbYIbDNHwJhjZBKObYGwT3JQWXZcWTxK89IHDTdJ1BR3T2GjSScOnNxSTRMYADfs6MgqEht9AQvbom0goL7kbmUiF7IJKTBWBwuH45h60jwOb9lhU@S06/FbJ1p0dCWMVZU1yiMAWdB20UmGBp8KB0HmPaXRCpShQuzQvCxwYA4IJVkq6CPIveI@tRzD05fHGfxUxpNn1PWQXYGYKeVhywKElPnuSw/uSLWzhvdisx2ToNWO2vHhtIi0qj3dGWgtjdCduG@tHVLDI0XcgwhYEtsGu269TZlOf7i0y8vUidxDuLfINURbe2L5cyBsPQZ52spLxn2BLO@VZdopAWhvMAPs0WyIDrxoUn8VJf2GPXb//7V//7/Tvf/sXf0v/7m/@9v/7z/8Thv8T/vyfYLPQ4TXAn/8F/vx7/Plf8Odv8OcvtzIR@Mix63d//R/g9n/8j/Tv/sVfWEn/5u9c/ugaEaRg1CbnX/1L/PkT/Pm/XP7YGvCv/swCxCwu/wu1Y1p5AOrP/wtNQ2mIZY3sr/@epl0@MDA8tuTdW3380et9hWDNhnsSenydbv3yQx3ZHvL6XIDXvmM3dz5sAO8Wcp3D41k3fQ/MGcuXDLU0z/FD9Nu2o1QD7R8eTRjVCA5A3uZ9MHrs1QE31P6/p49ptw9hIJo8gpS2dLhdf7verk0qwvpcDFCHh6jZqDDsXVMC01sK5JvMBJZGEKctZEbKWjJi87eCxz87A4jLkSzJ9LBeyi7LyQ2THto@RRP@N1NdFFochqxHeMhptpTtgsxuFbijbl41G5TyOgamjBt3/@2sJEKYaNAkkG3Nb2Qs3hAu@F@j27Sc3W0K1eKrDoOfHpiY422NtC4oTbtc34BFTtvwXrS4IrvwFr02wH3oOPK48/DAPmDX7e2ti9qKC6EM6X0PwbBVKUtlrJPY3aTwVlJ4KwlotnASXRMLh1/RQAYO1IvenXgr25aK2s22ES7sOU47IBkwF7TWA/2iPDWG6beoiUbeVXZvkW@hZB/Tdj95UIjOOaNd3jcZAOdunvTrttyPOvQG5m1D7c@J3N6J2Wmt9zHt5NnqFIR71GsurVuOTe1rud0Cv4KaffR9Z0Hh0D@xoMB3FhSPfbug182KeXfQv8/fb6sdR02sNfwGmdXxD3YGKBwa/xpEb6OOkGKdBD1emPJk7ClPb67Snj0nsEI84zzcvnPsqr71yDtOYiqqKVjLA581FaYcKlrBW2es73sRgn2k@UBRdcHYfihIshysFTc@lMarAwVGNT8@ZC/ZBwDjzqP1JPPuuLIe2WwrNGcd246oLUah5fn0JCmS@fQExqcsejcMxNsgj16vbgrPe4fQVn7P2rStah4VDwcxvd/GSexdK1tT4seeqmYnuqGQDA0TOl6QYfJFDzl@jG8uICzBKpJHdNAi7ZkeLzJxqE7UgaCo@EAe5n6FvrTBjQRxmkZo8dOcn@a3KLIn0R7ez3ntrFe/Oit9FfZw3nX@8C6CHWb4af01j5Gz@p7int4tzsrmlNf49fQ2tultfJ1eUdIN8zXNJBJXe/D664qOeDYYAHBDRuTbZPjtR23fkLNDyjoaTza2Mnw3iX3B4GH4Q0ozAJqxwYMiyId/fWfA3Zrw9nv8/3oDOtkL39t8xJhtLEHfTApo@5EpmkHOMlB4wQPgJS/qnrfFrUU7/51l2RMdMsPz0y6iuBR0noaOqWmCYqz3WR3E35B5dIl4I/fETyJtJe6hSZ/56XH4/SbKP/UFmVsKfY8N6d/C69S4LnB9oq@@r@Ko6IjSU63jrD0hP7tjipGHXAjQ8Tsiw/lnXu/7YmWBSGvpIZtxhMLS@/wjC3evVTMugqatPRBVBw16QJ5hJycHaEttaT0YJ1uvvLD1qDX@WC1ZwecFv8kQ4IP1QgPWvynW@zX1Wfesq/QdI8IaNrhbZXz2xcGIT5@8bcNfx6Jv15SsMqwzpZ1W3rFO3mtx6WstviUVjkxaVsn3ieS3hO67ZW5L1CxkGxWW@3VDyBvMOU6Wed6zjdGK@WqLqcobnYBx2GKq8s6o8rRHoa5zEk1n4uGmacu@8FISBEtwncG1DVdECHPQJ0ugnLqhXesseZGUCadtWS12zD2PtugWF73b@4hbUJQTxoXcl3WZ/Ltl8m/K5HfKXPeA3SK3gCh@p0i7FbB5vtYEsiCa72hnTMKZO1y@prbho6icjnuvX9yS@1jy0@6Z@xgUsltwHxc8oJTdffdxngQM93GDBMbu4ysIbPqW@xf3sdMtEECHWxL4jPG2Csd73n2c83hfKPKiI6fcoPt43aYA88m6JRx5sZZXe/auv7peVRUEv2VU@mmUGAMuKlbr/tFPviH4J6D2wTCQ@DFNh48IME5AdgaNrRHDKgeGjSB5k4pn3/Bx7CxN2esbmzUUSPeltxZVUEqmRB@5D9y7ysgiDFPJ4iNcgUDUm8f7KaLZNzOzb5Fjlw4SShp5t3zCvSCxB/oekn4PwNuLOPImv9NeuyisBvw@OjHze3S@IccpjlCEzgDePWQhU392f6VS2Na7tNitv91Cb9cIsBEDDojVSgTtlk4HGw5tU1KYpmq7QkJScbdP2s6DH7tTovS@yka0gt0z30km0XbNUDFsd37v16qzlQ9J21FBmHgferR62XpcILoYkza6bstStTofkLClc/rkyWEBxTZvBwmcpW78ZKx4bxhy8lpFEs21qyYhcxCf5phyplX6Zl8Gn/H4ddNXJyeY4EAjItjKuS7F0q/qr7DfVct@dwxqhwmvCthnWO8fSt@a118dZV9RLm@KfduAmOin8969xtG6hA3LYXawZZl/TdbemPh42r1l5FuFrrG/svYdtq3nBN/g2@u5hYULrQR9ths5xoXZcfh9Rr21SORZ0DFagliSjceq@JrSTdW@TqtV8X1NjCk4RsPlVzewvtvA242H@EgF9Fcst3o5vu2H7FOs@zauqW/tXFi7Dip6ia0P09mKBHVP/NfWLloQUX2q56uVchcG3UQi4X27FYG9FvJuxnHqq9sE62lL2I8nJ5AXBqLvxFDVzY8PiuutSxmJAGOAI/s2lvjZfdxr67Itff6q70I@C3aLozau8aYbcDtaCU0dDodsyearCQwRTM8RZyNxzFvgt5/M1nDXCKUDN3Sensjw9fSEzjlPT/Yohk2z3kb6w4H9Ro/w1lv/Dna9md550youAEwn1jvn7AU4@8Fjyw/lAN/vuH5P6zrXVDElx9kB14dwi2rtGeGJsF7rtZBOjPX2RpBUTziKU9hwDB@Os3IhNC58EtdKu5yPlqGDZ@cZmqrYr3ccW68AJSf5Gc7SKyF7qsw54gZilUKe6duiyHLIcvbFyBvbyMmY1uvxOMVaQnZ446eFQZDs@IRTMOUYS5p1sM7a9cPwkkyEYOKjBTzuycIE35oGsrtnNflaglYZFqXBAASJsU8ZtRxcmvgitYAqBnKbd9@2ybvv7OPIbJ8wcuSfvQ4M7PTsPPFv0OE4WFMpP3B28wXGopsMjU/1h4iTFoGCbwIuCSuY9G/l/ehZenevrPPxIr6Pnids2V@skQJaRwaRV7b4TD6/bC9N25uWRA9s7Vw6h1dQ9mEjabJPGUQfNc3jOnA5R3pg0HKb4GTeeRbeg6cwHFMfFKJ40AOM5i3fGjBwFTTayPaad@2SqtA/0JEwefcRlEesVFIs4LB29nawQxpkRWIt7z5bwbh@6Lt@wM1E6sMB6kJL1jC/I8oYJkeTbWSZ/mijszZUsCtbXcC5iW3dRGCq8WFPwR89Lh9g8bm8rh1MAG/vfnywNO/brKAUvX9gmv14p6hmMpnmhNXr55lBZpipd@E@Gyr7OqNogWEKF3I/ky/1ludqojkTw6Fm9ybbi/hqif5Cky4muQutQEnR7sR3F1mkLqKrWC6Sy/ChW/G8LEYTuVvx1hAyspBiZqPxTV@oaz1WN6SrynWlvmKKrZv24GYk3nU6o4TSoLT6XXZwsxBukh1l1m6lSsaN0M5VzHFlZE7ZZTXRibfmipFtN7PDy2VpPl6U4mpXiuVuhERb1C7m/DKm8Rct6m7WHMYbF8txip30l5mc0e8mfD6mm8sOkhd8/068bOSu@gM91ouNGykuMptcitpyeHWhPJdHucaM92mjYik@o5RaaTYXop1xT75Q7urtdi@frc3HrHGn9UfRzvXU7CX1eCQyzQjDUTRWmpp6spzNXCXMfKbULsq3bfNu2U7WKPPCbCZal3xK9s2qJh@Z5luMEWovLqWrxjx@EW6qF8qlXBrVxufT85qsTcf5qFRtTqL64LbYU8Phi5vG7KJbpvToZaebrI/CyTy/4JmrmKpOIs1UpaxfL6bZ56rQyfGNrNCLh7Kx2wI7uq4u@eqsXK93alqnNUkYV6x8VwyNqOot38hkx8XyJMk2K8tS8rzUmOZypcWsFxYHamba70Sub@PzckUodW6YyAU3Na99Uq4qM6PLS2PZbl2VbivGHXTr60spKi4X2XZWF5/zOeO6XmYq@njYiI6UvtZOSDmVv6yVomZpnLmYd@5SpexYEGu9sTpuduTO1JTyI6ZILXPjm1ZPmBel1ZwrRMvtG2ZUqPNmIjOINJiRKPbGctVYDc7Lq0Fj2hv0U9XzUF54vupn27F6QWOvi0a0oiypbjMrSqv6jciOa6mL0l2vkJGulViuJmi184vZIhzuSmJtHluxi9tRMSot@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@DvWESjclZcateq1khpscM@02yrHnctcwinyrJGWjkjLNZ7vn40nubsk1jcVq2oz3ZHFZ08OhArWodK/b/EgdGEXjjh@tbot3yvU0HL@tjsSE2R@zE4ktt8VQoqLVfXlfTT7vDZbx9lSY8WAZajcljc1mRqMqVWUniVl2mTJM5dy4qvRylxkpkyknwzdaOHExzp1fLPpSu9WuXPQ5NXrXy0Xi1d4gFO5nK4VBLToZJGqVRLSco5q95U2d7eeTEjvk5NzochnVUuVwNs605/WLm1FzqFTkXKazELMRvqnOEx1OVFrCKp5grkO@0TB1qWRC0Vqcapl5s1UuziM@5ap0Ha4tl/xtj5tGOPG5a/j47mq4qrYFTpWH5ec622xPyzlpNGrHs3wzVM02QtOVMee0co1K5WsKmy8vZsX5sNEJGVr@Qkv2FpV@rlYTelo/oom9amYhhmadzt3NTauqTG5vJhf1RK@66nOjWNsU6/HqwqSeweRpz8qtYm@RFw1xVJ89K@eL6W2bibbOJ@VWf@Ybpe66s4h0Ww2VK9m2yE1LN4OE2aostOtLWZSZSbg6YKh5q7ZamUJGLVTm192F2F6tMlLWeGYXVwxXPi/lb01fqlDM5KvNBqfL1ep5OZ/hJvPrefk24RNWjet@TBo/31E1RZHD@l1DTmRDESPciuVXOX50HpqeZyfNy2aK1djWRfv6@oodyvyET3Sr@Xjnmu9kMpdXy0uRa9dqWu2q1aSqPuX27q7JVJtyOSWWS/WmGivN9OtOJ8HN1cwNFypFJ715eZGdX0@nnUnq0tc1BS6irgSBrc/lMiNcgOwkKWE6q@UqNWMZfl6NngezvHrbTmW083gmtxT7M2G2CmXyMx9jFBfzflzSkuFmd3EudvnrweCqnh1GtJnWjOdi1GVKvFbavdzwOrUUri7K7eLUFBr9XlTyGSFt1LzJtIwWv5TO@fhw1jK6MnQ@UYs1s7mUId/lk1e65Asl@SzFd665GlMexm4rl311nltct5d5mHIkWbEWiqlLpT1NjpWLKyN71Xm@SiYHrd7FGAqeDu@GvNTyZfs94UaUK9Td7VV7XKhN28zo5vY6UWtd@JKriH7@zKvDcy61bK6qoZAgpgaz0nQR0cp88jx5VeXly0Wl3hKFQbwRvpHPlRWVVxLDUEZk57O5wviWsWyyMBCzrYqi51v8RUJQaxzDLDp3ZrVzm7wKn4duQo3JPBQ2rudMSOwq0rJb6XbDfSo7M660ToOdFXwXZqbbGNX5c5mpdOqllbosF8JGK1PJiVfT@VIrLyU9cseXz3NyjZdYMEti8UFTb41X2VmP6oiLci6bTNyFL0CCDENOzbtRTuANbbAYMeXr6YW8GE3Hbd03WTB13113EUsN20OD4cvlZqU0L@gx9dIYKVQ8zocvOrqWMOrPk2UpZ@aH7ZYczaXag171ostcN8Wr1E2ucZcQYjWm9CykOo14iC/HOjzD1tXJzIQRiR@MqfIy1Nd5WdC5xLT6HCtMp77@cjY1fdpd4vwq2RmMc@yM53yRTE995hbtSzkkVRLCwKh25rPbYgcsRKU9aylU8a6lRa6kC7Fx0a5ej9lapr4ymWyqw99GB12dFRVxVo@YscuSMEjwYr5wNx7lL0rPpVBXfA7NWVm/uYkUL1gqIfqyptqXmfaNdqOswpyQ6VaT1/P@KjcZVkThohTO6916vN@44uQCDKPSczmktYvn5bt@Tx4yoqpUG/VQiLqLhwud2/ozO@vf1FZNdXGhDy4zNTlyK5YUtXbbZvM3OlNJZIs3uVH9LrdMxmu63BOag2RTmfjOIyrPZZRynEoIMyHb7jAtQYqwicWqx40Fhr3rjMfJC2YVN1ZMRjHmo@RgleqdT9jOXUU9by7HzPlkcVfL3rJTwceyNV6jbsxVLXZ@3vFdLc9bpYHcKok8w02WI@MiOxUu572beMaX1EJNX6HfHi7KtYHWKTCJXi/JNiKRTtR87teWxk2FaufLF5FEfmkuxMJ4WlkkL7RMvLFctG6i0fHdaFFNNuL12IKdqeNCVisOYox6aySURfNiUMwKBfFaNK5XPX5CxVfTSqmYLPhiAtetde9CYoF5bvRlczgQm1e3kUac4WMX1dr87i6fYSYJcVQoyecwJs6568WyMeqOezdVIyJRarXrK8VX8VXj7qbSV2qdy@thbz5IJGr6RXuUmq66Wl2q@7RVq9RTz/O1iZxf3YLAxeup2KglF1od6TZfD1UpM97JzMEGZ7NlaTlgSrHQlaiELheT89TtpBMfd8ft3KzeXYxH8UYipk6FVcLsPMemQivRvZw0GL7XnQ994XNKbayWt4WbqF6uzLWyWVOFq1AyXL4btyaFacs3yV0Ve2auE9J64U55PvXlYmAVJK/bqXCldzXKlsbnN8bFTThFNYvScpocncfPfTUYTKYjo5psy2F5xnQYuT2fCeNJiKvkuba@6LWK5X6lH04ymk9KzM2r@PNlt3bHmVpUYShjGe/POd9FASyIvNSNNXxtUwtNYC4Sup1FrpRBJGwot40Gb@bUxLgVSQnRot5W1PZCHbXD0s15YjznpasRlRVW/ajcqnf6lcVq3k@No32uMWtlirdKJ5JTtOHC0Nl46irc5p5rEz1SNbVaucVnlZsJx4lz30LO5q/1xozqDyqZfqf4PBVn7Wg1E80sb/uh6PRuNmKV1W2hGx7VepmhOK93oqv6PJLtn7NKfSJpEz3MhJptpTBOLloXwhV1uSoIy2HyJltrR1tXo9Q4Ig/GjVpoOa5KIn93Z0zZUndQvmH7pVg7e5MaX4hGRki0UuLliFlUetW7eK4vREOUb1iaMOFcmY9cFm595iUvx56lFVsxVylRWVZaUq8xmGW0cn/UmlayF0yWDc/OF9VJ5KLORKZcdpLMX@ldXaaEQiyzaFWv48bwLmO2o2otPEtqdzVpcBvu14YcPwnFk6CDr/u9u2UrU8/Oy93KRcPIKIOV4NPnV8p5qVjMKtSF2Kk8G8@cKk4z0Va13L15vsnog2asZxoldvEsMMulUr3M8fyymykZ40r7sqGUEqFJP3uduBn2y0pLrUmRK4pPJca3CUZp8JfTkBCtZaLF5/Y5/1yaxevqWDH5ZuGONSt1UHalWKuqdeeTVW4YEheRaOHWqA762h301tGKCk8v6t1@XRwpi3n90mxfRSYNdtyey@O4wmm@aCFVrXLsIIKTsNitqkxU@Wpg3jYqsyudYYar@FTQzoUriSqHtUGmVI9fhrnz824@1WInz2UhnLyOTjPzcLV@7VNigpYvDSZyKDeuj4QbCaYMnXhtdBlqVKTW4G6au00tG9Sq2xNTymVnrl7lxvP8eDZqthYRmF4122XDaNRvzX5pFu5dJuReddhv5ou5Gz7HcUaiquQK1bE2bfcm84tojBoVI7ej68SlNIiPEyVh2b2aaqna5aqUG15EfV3lMml2OVN@rsqj50rPNHvPCanduLlkOtkEr4SelwnzdthhDOoiOSmcR4XEqjRkEy1lMptO@9W6opaWtZtrYHMiHGme95iM1rmpme3@hcDfXrTA0r9UhVLj9lJrnN9e9Kd9hZIjIL45Rr86LxvF2/z4jp2X6suexPrG1at5NZaIiamebxabVIbTfCzWSUwuK7NiXtPji2vQ@oPaslYW6pVrip1cdwtj36XIskn9etWeResZ4Tbeu56L82gsn1kow2SyFVrcXJ7zN8meVppPWpfs4IaZ36XGxoRrcfUMr4pVKvusRZb5hVkIxQpX8YvbG2EUn/cL03ApM290SnEzVRE7nejzvD4fC5UiKzYXs3m4VqzemEo0tmjf3I2voBViFD9Y3BQSwnVU6Iek1V1OL6o9pcVlQswlE5632jc@daA8VwTfuBYuRrR4IbSocTAzvstOL/vxXmskd86zF6kh1Y/yBV/TiJfu4s@3z9eSfjvyJSagcpJifXZzDSZJz2w1o4sbMdVlV@1cssP1iiu2cMVkohcX01QpHL4sp8pdymjEJiAtz/Pw7WVeDt/U2s3o1Jev5Bf9YeOuVc/Nr5N3XXZS6zRmlzgZizChuVgd1VvLSnHRkoR4YVwviFnKV7qZG9WUJtbz7YLO1PpiMToaX5wXz4XpFT9dFBRfaFBqLWfP04mQvLyWOUFXinVzmOEj3eQ4suBLWub5qk0tL7jCJZtLtpP6WOIvR5WWMTJmHU2UMtHn2MJn1kc16SqWrzdvlVFrWKnofO46nDCE/Lgxid@1RoveTCj0LynRTM14eXFeiZtKdlmUblvXN5f9RmjJ15KXlaK@CPWY4nMjNDOZVrJRaw56FV0qj2Dg9HVbqpqUQaWYQ/WG4rRhKTRvZ676yYGROw8ly5eLakuq@EI3hfooHzZmuo8ZTqrh/EotXEbEeWJQv7mahPTcrD/0XdUSzN0oq84rVMzsRzqcMU7VRbbbbTNaob4yjOtkq@e7upEZoR6@S2QvVmyzF9H602E32Z2cz5673evnXrtxAc156xPijetnanBzdWEkxBTP9lvZXDmjzrTQpT6pi9FJWe22wl3R113kS/Pn8FWoOCr12EpluFpl@Uu9oyTzk951jluOWsk2FSlUQ/27iKBdtvLP3eJwOuJz5QUfuVUvDN9ttLKYnuvJRJyNpmacEWlPJm1fMiNLvkRkuByGs4VZPM/09XqHKlR9uY6qQi@o38W5CmNE@xXZNFqJZqOQqueKuYvyVeFWLKcaJe721te9KeUKmWb88mo4jl51WSPLZK@Ho0aYGpVz4z5jmsmp1JCKRuFczy@Gd@ObybQ3T8zKRnelXHFTaTBhRU4bd8pKIp65aT/HqqFI4Zop3K1kJZyILVJUnxf7l4xcH992klLhgunKQ5hA50H@x7fXU50XdWOY6kDNr1dKIteqDtr6hTysAYVyb6rx4iQljYdC5I6qM41kMdGRr0S@2q1PEt2edNu8jCTE6QLmr9386krMM9DqrW5jOA3dxgtgukajz6XOcHIzq7SNeizfbpZrUar9XM@LbKlQLrfvzD5bqYYGxZnZSiQvCiw/yY4rhWW2ly3Ni3yrc@Eb@cLNPj8rtjNyod3njMXyLpQK6RlxRMVH8eusmGfNeawt6tHc5bAa4eSSuqheJrVJvXYZzl4WbkR1rIeyNxnnE28vUxMpthyImcx5u9TNDajMTS4/CrdFg68rvnmJgGWLMveHX31UiKDrCgGjZqrUp8mrSe1jLk6@cvAEOXkCH2/fOXcCnX22DxIQ7eergRYox@9q4RPCx1YhZG8ziGdf49biyeu9xQDrHCdALniOB31EzrsWdzZCXTpmXpPxUVK@RgDZ8SQ7KLgPRh5P/sE4hi/Q4HdQApvIE3UewhvvN2kjHMFzPlg8s@vxZGvL08NuU4MEQpNxigj89Lt@wFMVfoSMZAu4UC16923rh0528gNxhqaQk0ZcgaCLZLVPxUBMuyis1sT49dkMFDmQxdlY@8rbPDiGTYbiKXK@B634Tf/kPvXoP@LTLlowJU6ZGFN93h8P1OFMpGVaG/UW/HL1TNOxKB2BssI/0j4sk42nGXJcYwJ@k3QqZJ/MRD6fyLmzeDwVOW4ODw1203RgfbrTR9pLAn78OXadvJFS@mjiSKF1yMfkPv6YVtKhk8m98nii@Hxe05c2fazPgxE/st4TbWp7It6bj@SpfeaIvnYercezrtH3VxXpmqrwQ9Vt0OTFgdvPnJBDuJwONOG07f40E3hT1bdjRJQnbrLTEd9G4S4x9yqnpDpw5lITcOtufSqBjG9UxZ8P03j05G061vDDBzxC48T2ndiuwBdKm/ZkiT@mPhB@4hY4Pk5/fGwfCsPTKLcfPpA4yYq0aKElw4PJJ04qr2pLO7NkgTw5dTndQnnmwb1Vr/97IB2oHsjkE76ZRAcwC8Ri7w44DajJ1qjXogrDZUFZ74PiOT7eEzzlhP7opDkn/iA8yg05d@fJpCVySg9cTmkblJyBQXvtEydI7L2ED70RV4Izt5X0YTSdaGT/OWjRa3MEX5n2pHGSvs4ZNKb4ukMPzSIzJIdobAEMvOBRaDPOFLabxmkLdHwjD19hfRBfjZydDwTznK4vUTfiwweIr6@SPB@sd/J5aFO1HCstMuy8pBpeu6mBcXiYqltzH9PED@4EosiW6MlW6ghSsa7vJE8gecKZw3eSh4h7aryXrEMyvqnvnWQJkq1nIvenq5Bu7fS/A2CilyeI65OpPpmcJHusAz3wKJAXS2F7aJ/PYexaBGirYaz22M1P20ej0B@t1rGEbUe8oH8SsbIAUKQ9dufB@420kFQ8a9ZjycVWmRZP6C/0NwuznSOBxU@kJFC7WL73aAc/vUUA9D9QpfTbdKdwq7XXFd2RnyAMOwNsbWBWhP7ll69RZgvirvyxj470WS2EfrhbNbS4tcFjvWJs065WppWdaX8e@@iYbe3m@Ehs6uF0yvBGhVh9a9OvRUnpQxmA@ON2NLo8eelPm5h745E@XmuPDR@tbvFtPobfSA96RJEe6ad7myD//VzlUO4hJwcjcm@jLPCcMO7kDTuNNXRgF/oMoNfcfCVn/I7M2L3011b2@2pzAPSRTk14c2IpWh5MwzObwD3kcVa7busEC9mh@9iKx1enSbvIpHeQWefpPQEC8xRowJHNUePOmCgpQeuZVNDzoXDUT1zMLZCXDZscZfU9fPpn6FzIOHvInuLbZHZVEr2HNW/A1/VGfp297nKvqmdp@v2Vu7ceanZ/ciON9Ft5IlL3CUbJYzpErw9uOqFfvq2H/nGc@bJpvh17x/C8ryucRnck8XtE8OUdRn9TyHarEH6kdzg@JS/x1r45JJFDCPcPShvX@icnxnG7tPr2uxYYUnWym440WwidBDCUt3P5bZvrbKM67dMXn0zHuPFvrDDy3ngiFWCyn1Db6hync0UyeG/Hro@OIhzZTsEn2dHC1B3KJNGxbcEMdvIF@SdsZovJyE/o0wNV7Xscg8k2GAgG54QOAPJbx1mtzSrLvNwUD8XZRi89sE/5cMbdE4j5aEeRcQUi0Pi0ZROJOBqQbnOC3WbLvpEM8o5Bko6jERTlPH2AzoqW9qGPX8cj9NoE@rA3k6Px8UwycnKlrefJSLyjHlw5TkHHUGwOa2p96sL4dUMgzBlMtDfnW5I2eNmzymCd4Wmfbvlle@oinUhBtInXje54QXpP1tScnrqwmLXAv/zh4CMzNXSmJymMoMxofFc7dUALivVqnWN8y3IgiY7C@JJkW5sQv2zihAhiAi2FpQUVYe6xX6SMp4i6vJR1Jh1xWmQpPL@X@I3LwqwPVr91YoumGgvyu4TJQig41UyVpNgFkbPr6F@kXzbnqYbIU0T2jMEm55Tg2cB48PkCK3Zp@UoGWMtAYvFwYu8WinvMSRSu68HlwvZDQm1/0vtHyggKHD9EIlD2frGmU9BcRJJfKMNpejxrDVmBD69AULZOmdCI7ygWQawTY0nuofp4z2LAiiEurij39jyFIg7BmCKrqoZCjq6gmP8UGGAx/kOjmS/U60H73QqWxzp6uVt@zPiIIDmwzn4Juu3Gi97qeFyg1SgfsLKI2yovvUFO9C/hERZrswm7whzZafEKzyO0ahBgyd2baqzhvRY4YQl53Mm@M5CXIftUDw3sKOTdJptnK1vAyeYAb7Hiwze5wfE8HgRxLUxUoDgnyDIQbfHiw4YdGESOOOX71uUb91jm45p4Kz3wJj2wkx600i2iNlBBfqhvgI63gVwHXzZwL7RrA@Z/U1aahkqXKuR0qaCqb9F98jVYIwiTNGkDfLZuSksq1wmnOwmBrZSf9rS@lfJxJ89awNfp91a6Ld9hu@XXVO7Aft4tH6@U3UACOYPBfmTxlZQGFUn@ZC0/rlOIhqXxWCUrO7Y3ETurU9oLIrY6CYCawLeUY7c9S2@w@FhH45A@4zo7/ewK2ktSnzyvybBeCvSmY@3pI1tcImX6COMWZCSBckjyxy0UBCcKGu303DMn89LOvNxCi1AfnWIp56TQ3Q4OVXvdxdPo1v0L/jidfZc4B@5gf@IHi/KFVXnrSYtdBhGl@9G1n0272sTUp4IVaVfqK6PIpuzla4z7lURFxRkoPyQvo3fKFKznQUR1qvQ/rvXEtqJwNMUbvq9TbE5vAFhHfN9rQkx8of7AHFHn3ASsQllY0Bm0qTlylD2187ANvlbegD4gQAV12phqmizZ57rRc/I4h1VPNhzDhxE2GLeMhiBVwgdELXg/huyHYyBTkK4i5jk@Z7hJMKaDgfUyaxrflgmqVZQApRmkMsrSes82HoMWth55EegpnuOKCliGad8WEVbLWb1n/UbyIOU8WGRVVbT6t2KCCQQVV8mZh/9/ccfanDYO/Hz@FSqd5HDrAGnTa6dpMzVGgGaMTf0IYa6ZDAEn8YRHhkdI5q7//XZXkm0ITXtzH@4L2LK0L61eK2kXXa1@NIyvq3R467TYm1rt/WHt7WFBZNpUXau8PaJw3XqKpD@8qR3Wau8OjwzDmd09yquN5aGJsI4OEKDFXBzoT0E3k3uMZmnYMGJQxgVM/RfJ/D4ZVQwjSEZkA75ckURQlVeLRHpRJj@vmAJzK/R3j2HcF5aM1Q4ahv84PkvftUNyrGEZeIfoLplP0qW8aTS7T0coQH1v6mo2Hs/WZIjGK0tSHlhokixBKK9MtkkS@aVVtNDchdzFgjQGKuj24HJ2T36klRhgnpqi@326AGSgE0WEUEQmI/YWKAF8w/EgnaA67SAAvSzlEtAEAGuj1TB5lgaDiPiXNOho4qPZcIWeeQe6ZqrQ@82orUBzT@Yp9L65gKlWqFiBdqjgqC1CFvrNqGcHnMFzN/BPRYM3WL3PojZnjt/tU0wj1vZd6F1CZnsNSPWiQNTjyIeEkh1CyRJ9MGyvz/hZN@BhyPyAiU7XFQANwAe2FwkeWkx4jhvDYN2yGEBgnh8xV3REBNki3yKsupiRl2N@k3V44LTh1a4LV0R9wtgUkYfImoDNZl07iIQTu3bAunHQ9UPOkDGjIULHtUWHNyoYIMnzGT/lXsTCtu26W4z6PY8HSPwGl3UOVNp1lxMm4rMhAu5EyFD@5IDwgEDXYmGXOwIf@BkHduygbymgIf8aQyb4yBp2x24Bc0b5J1KBenHigHeQaJBEGNfDSERxxFnL9xsk65AHp8Lh4TEzXD8kgcUhtxgGhCPUAAOkBd/huR6HguQmvAjGjLgbCd8zoZJ7IBig0oaiDRKw70luQUh@0EeoKAeqAIv12hzSA5QpSctGKYQgNScqZgOEIMSoyCbzeMsVLe45HD/7CKYnQm5ChYkQMwBMxNuzAWlMXGM9AV3yEZTV0JprUXUy0WR241Qg5So3aEAolLaQ2Jy2kjm05aqxc8vt2Q28p7t8yhTyvJN4x29wmPHJ2CqlPD2GQefD5ubdxjcYaLKP8Kp2QWmsuhgll6vri3R6NcOleVZM7mBPFtcWhgYyMRzfN@OZUKBqo5wKvHx5cXFqX8A6N7y4MK1fKblBxs9KKC@sz@UyFY/j2WBEy/wN21JRUCf7yte7JR0vF20t@5nxwWTV6ihRxfDyIgLWZiIVlACAjbBnpFuNgykroKQt5k1bEUXM2DYW6e3N2QJ@pn/nL3JsKCRA5yzPLVSruIYlMjDyCcvoByQUFERFBqFzAOkVoawskuT2ulwrosMlvzJQmboM5V3CMvC6bP6k@GVyvVX8YLs8EYt3TWmyot3BazftMsw5vimRMVUvlTlxVpamPfozNTWECCaFpkRFF1nV6ZPyviyO/kWlrdA8zlyJUziQjn0meriYq705Ot5Kb2fpsm3hrXOMbQPj3Z9U7pz@2ucyAzSwFJdfIJL0UW6pVquFMjAro/lklhl91d9gpnU6gjEVh@qbhIZ19JAv3QUXy8NgPE8fitRDN9wK7E49bjah50Rqjz68e//HsaE87s@XZ5b87yMeDP9H0oVZ9DqFaRp9KrQSB@Y9zSfBcgrRfbD2MCMG19OVRokY5j3znCnnCDK@hjQDIbsLjDAwxSAbJQwSMC8xvJ@fvDC0vu5smUoByhusmsjNZPBAM/wBTJVIB4bSS@b4kWrtAX8Qdtb8dRPPGFIKpFQsmdwtH0FzYXFB/V6pqR0O0NqGrhVjlkpJ6/HdQJ9BkoLBPpO8MOAdfHpTul2oRZjXYkVje6Vqp5JAxIttKnSQFgq5BCi6s4VuwTIxhZQzpW/w2FfBgfAThnqwlyGIsZmVPNDBe6TNWTUMBfn85DNU0f5@hukTQ0OqqYiS9v/N0DHF1kCkyAMNbAuwPnmUyTn7QkboL7@b7C@pqejVG@EcK41V76C5u9hRUI61S3T1riPIMAkrDyhDSesMh6Gz9HWWTJwbYvpP8iD4/6NMdsD/BAtOgJ5Li/rhdLpKflGSBFXKClavJJR0rU@MFY6p5dIsJvVzMN@LFXOTMaaO4T3IjSUQgaqdR53QlyHFyjsEgEqOdo1i@0UHvtSIbwawcvpCbfc3udM/nw4nd2UdkEsPFU/gnls057L0ETl8MeUWfo0V0LkYX@UL@XmkPgMXXNCLXT6yvUVJwnh9SH0OMl19RUaPrJWTaqIYDnULz9WpppqWbvwP6oRRPsqM9NfvMBX9cbCvbDsEYwptdPh6B0R3IHT2qciwEhvgPEFCd/KNnl7Iys/UKJ5gt3klx2UWkXuOxeCK1sw4FClfGui0A1EinL2Ritl0mSzXOFyMJXTyIZJDY@U9cmOCSJQtMptG6M7XrIDUaZBdZ9STmRL1NaM@nt5OMa5sIk1cOkdlIwJU0QVrhXUGFAxq/Gt8l3Lkr1GsJ5v4xZT8qgzlfiWa5mjlDlhwpb@3yCUCM841zi5hHMqlNBjeYmJJ62i6Pkgf4I9wHSjOdUwjWDNQxLpdk/7vP1wQoK5snYFlpW/TzIj0UQ5kn/f09AWfZNvNnvr4pOzMn4EpIA5SdP3cIME4a8Ijmk/bGlH3Dw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)

### Explanation

Gammaplex is a 2D language with graphical output. I used [this interpreter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/gammaplex/gammaplex.zip).
Gammaplex programs can have explicit entry point `@`. If there are multiple `@` the last one is used.
The code that prints 125:

```
@125iRE
```

`125` puts 125 on the stack in Labyrinth fashion (each digit is added to top of stack multiplied by 10).
`i` prints integer at current pixel position (which is (0,0), top left). `R` refreshes the screen to show the changes.
There is no way to quit Gammaplex program from code. `E` "ends" the program by entering infinite loop, user can press Esc, 2 to exit the program.

Gammaplex Abstraction test is included in the test driver, it prints 125 if Gammaplex interpreter would print 125.
Abstraction test requires the exact `@125iRE` code to be present, no spaces or other noops are allowed.

Gammaplex interpreter reads code unlike other 2D languages: it considers the length of the
first line to be the width of codespace, and the rest of the code is read in chunks of that length, regardless of newlines. All bytes with value < 32 are ignored.
This means that Gammaplex code may end up anywhere on the line, so this can happen:

```
................@125
iRE.................
```

This of course will not work in Gammaplex. Abstraction test detects such situations and suggests by how many bytes the code should be shifted to
be not splitted. Unlike Cubix, spaces can be used to align Gammaplex code.

Gammaplex code is expected to move from time to time, so I placed it *after* `_` on `#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF` line. Note that it must be no `@`s after Gammaplex code.

Test driver updates: don't escape printable ascii in test results (for Prelude/Gammaplex errors), escape everything else (for Incident) `[^\w]` → `[^\x20-\x7E]`.

Answer (score 7):

## 132. [YABALL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/YABALL), 5244 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTaxTaTbTbTbxRtRtRtxVkVkVk
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l@O6O4/111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPQs""o<
>-}

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"1
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002280 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5364 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgHdKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i890@0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQBvErXW2t1NiUShKisrKysrK6sqUejy5uAPfzjAD13VlEVf0SzaEk2L7hnyVDSCdGZBf@ZlMxoKUxRCpY3@ZCyqlnlMHdAcTcuqIPfgnra0kajKS9GA@BBN64bWN/gxbQ14ixZNgddFk9Ymlj6xaE3any1M0/mxNpQDmHMsq30As0RDN0SLpEdouqkq/Ljb41@lRF8VqBuQbtI5Ufll/ItFC9p4zKs9EyBjNJ2rZPKl9CsMcZq@1gxTRDyCaJoaRiZoep4XhVegSQDlDVkrpcvnr5I4lj4H0nldEec03zUtgxcsWVNt3lUNrTcRsF7WQIScyAtJVkSTEoDmM1p3WiCIAfqANkS@Z4NRkmbQmIUejxRapgVdp7sKPwgKtCIDbIFN0CKyjl5CujIw6bk@BgymNha3STRpVRR7tKmLgizJAimdFueWqJpApRmkZWFEz2RFoXuiAhk2JAl@QEZPzK0om4Ag1dMoGj6C/qoC67tDEWBUccUEUQfuIRM0ZDZwZMWLmcHrOhAJjKwD4ZY8BpmRLbdJi7wpo1RCFlNUe4R/@lpeNZpXt2tJT2We5oHeiUFwm6KBjRAkeOmBaIiAkl9LjGdmyBawANmbpqsib9ANQxS9u7K7UyQUpmEJFlYkSJrv9NSdrxTc0Ix2jiCvW9SBEW7cXFI8HUzRh08n8E25XCdUvpyjvxw@YNgWVWhq3fDwXjr1G9pkHh5E@M65LtM3XijASgFXFJrRdIvhAzoQGLCAQIbHIIYC01BQV7YKpk9ftcWWcNlQPWgNuqjSLT@pmTAxDOyOG6byI6i0oql94CdU1pioyA@VjrHQBIIGvclPi1PgmqbabaTNCIcbAxkazcQm2eoAtlIhDAW1ArLncHRVrqkpEwIHOU0LBRC4AlkRY1GiW7TEywpmgXREZVNtiOZEsTDPRO1hy4PSEHtBekWGoPUQaKxNoTgekJII6EvjrR5IiAJgaAiNVBWTfvev/12v3wc8aUHQjJ4jri26pwlE/fGEWNApNAqspvIKIQvg/Fi6nR0KmPKK3OMtLF5dOEUQIkipM22i9GgNCjRmMnStAT@F7ihJomCJtpDbGtNPj/mRrTdkW3Kh4mO@Cw1LCiBlk2oH6M9ZaCVBpA6IzATGE0tK0AE9T7tN5ifPp2PPp48PIhDnDXqPDhmmfwICFzwiUXDn/prktNJbGg2Ui8Wbmtyj9IU10NQQHRBol5DSdFH1uHdwuP1uo@v2BlGfebwnckoISrLa87hBxjNQrtt7IqSEe/n48eRV7u0SAcsMsWBvFT2C10WBxiF9YsqMeVkN6gu6FXBCW2ma@YQcx@TgVjTy5XXc1I44IAMGiqWG8gFqKGgqoqh72CDnRS2BcHurjQn7KvoKh1PhY/nR5z5w@7arTjBATXcqin21IWuotRR9MAEdDUxRTR20t4GiK/AgPCYqcQtGbT/dJWJNND8oFqISZ6LbEOku6NGVGJEeafc4zB9APelg2PSgFdxuhxZ7W/0ZdAF0act8o5QVbQYFE9pw@AINomLhfB@aCDLbFUrbFbJLJDG7VRupoFcQW1ekE4GuDH0Bex2odkf0t@oI4OGQDQPY7L6ypYLG/AKwCPaQuOk3tCxBlxqDljAWtCCi6gEdJNrjChYyId3QBHsFLRc2EIpGd7vam55mGUw6cAe6esl8tUNh5dM7VgIMQJI4oxVe7U/4PppMKmThBUHULUdfQU1MCzTS62GHRAacMTRoDqjDz6/LJmOJM7pulYG63m49Z0TkUck4RlNAAZ1K847ZR/dkA7STsnhdOgBMXxXu@hlBdgj42fUOCStDAIRMnIvCxALlBoI8G8jCAGQXqVNt9WiPRa@Lh6jt0kHBB6R10UgMd/ZjiAoy6ygk410UAWzRt3hgjEVUZzsRpPG3I76OmTfHexBraxJhPNiKDTJ8EGTvGzjHmqrtQQqMXKNFkN0Uux3AIKujMQjj18r6Ip11bSGumwjaDLQH9HyQv4Fl6eYxDBeyNZh0gyApTMNYFK2KisLCWMZCtjQ73FW0LqhnE/onsyqBESZdef6qQiRu3YZDk5qCHSaZdAoG8OcJSJ3HLZmgOEl8FoG3klxEgRMU9q8LAAlQEBjlkUyikgugVOoLVfC4gqQrBaHTufy0CzuuywsBzLXmS1Yboxai28Q@QIMvY4DmkkBbObqfqH5@74i3HgOIeed2B4earHq@uD9@/Og@dp@Bhv/48ROETjH0CUM@CH0ioQAJIVwQQySHn4Qw9Z7kwLhH98v9CvPc@4jNNsfRaSnrHv7@@Dj86OfvOecawqsXVB1oNoAO4AXwuL2pFAa9XtfZDCoa7Ep27Ws2Z3tEGmqi2qfEua4ZFl2u5PJP1XTjIuViJqbBKHKXUWF8fRpDD4a5jGtPfpiUrLJDsKZpVoo0GMYT6AIAOZM1ytIm0Odh/iGPZatIZj@KioK9abRVahbK3SCoyqJFOaPRRtZxIrRpG6gHgS9uz4kkQxuvNZxJicJAo12HYRfa8jvzURz2ndQIpk6c2ehWfBzjxziTDApUXxDogGbfriMdwAQC4uwyCJM5qu/zISSZba4jHcgkQYkzzqDRXUV@4dgXjF9PN7fGkW2M@9Lfz0R4s2d@7BQawxJ7WldU5rFIQFSkoDVfBlEtxCKUfaEDvfcg9uSl5st9GSgL@nhgLr1K4A3KprABY1UJpiZ0STbJcsJ2c1LrjvBAueyOGt4dhVyblNDGZNxv57q2sRChBUEYaagWN6EnMOqiOyhgmv42pySbA/KzA/qGorcpJLc57krkZw/AsWM7gejjRB5ZconTQDTfNA0m/TMCRkYBggxYJas8UyMXHA/20bM7su0Q0xWlCUwNma6sYvgbYIFkgkBK3a78HijwBUlfXfeAGZPuPraBcA3eGD/0DuOtiWEpYs@5/rc/7kEDvG2eAb@AKY0wWgeegG/YVAHp3dZysuIN@dnfsgRmOFFknrCBhL6FUuBx2skr68B@1Kh66UBgwBvQuItV44Jw4g8Mo1@RM5tyQ1QmPXF13V8IYfGuiWXnVuUxqRFc0V4k4@U72V8ZiHZ@nLYbisb3CBZ7OUUWN61tt4s45/tQOWZLI4Em/A46V3YcvVk/AYPFmti/uGTyrXaVdfx@rb86kGyU73IiTDb5rvwOF5GI2HtybXcXNDACksKP7OATBvdX1a6MIff7YFg51/fAwIqGiY7OCyIzI5d3VYw6MXW7KTD0FXyGYv@@B7Ja310H3gOEairk59eIHREEAfoGkopLloEtFsmvmKrw3QUaYYNfLz9YIBlHQb2kBJ@PDeOQup7jbhZHdf39/GgDkPzJ5P7c9joqQSBokiSK3@qzMO7IY14JhHpbwXdV8Mpo3YT2gA75KQ/mrMKbICCWw2ZxCs1Cfr4mtDiUCBOFNzahr4jshpzVUsZ7s@FNHl0WNEV2JHN1854ufD2P2KDBlXLys8mKd2/52wPTHYfpwDq0v0NrgoUz0nfk6DvUkz0ZxOn2lmAEtfd4J2gz/L7bewfaVLR/9w9Zy71UfYf6CShEMmA6@DZ7T/iWuOLSJvnZz8XRXqosQdkbf0xfa5oxEFWTDgVZNHBUsh4PA7ai2LPTRrHyvkybsqKZdJ38fo0XYPKbpv27X5q32SbzakAY2H1sHd6fbS9RZHij0@T3ncbllb6mxBJ9hoefdyVgYkio5Z3r92q4tYbiuG9qqLW5o6mcc31XtY/g/1vCQVZaDVyA2Ap@xYrap86ciev7FYQZAa4q7q9cgU2QnEHGnqe91wCGMJjxi9X1HzF6vMfd1eihL4ixDNYcZkgmIGAZtgH9jykt8vXSet@no96gjX@rEluNO1JE0Njk902T0iGW@5U5OJb9fo0lKRNxIu7VIJXuUASx@Zru@H6iWKcah87KBgPMw03YNdTSmQp@F9U4nuPdVxUOr8jQyb9pzexVNTpY2DpOnasQqGLgbca@OtF3GneLd7WJWvs65wb6qmdrvR0iMeXXaqTEt22mHTPcFMl3vwI5RvcCmPBqY7Ah1O9ofwcpWQSyf3cQk5gN5qGM61HGV/Ee0@uVSrBfwR6BVpVHZgAXtb5P8YTem6kT4GQS5mKqaC3w9z1u71OkXU1Tfk3rgD7tyWimgfGJ3gjfaqU3to@zaE1v1iRMXN/oSu@tRthjjTNtBO7hFPndhq5ClSwyOHxPK79Z5fvKqLW15vetOSGM2GTJxzSEVfg9emvYublgIhj/KsGr9TBmFfgasmQw/D32kb4yesmSKi7D2guvG3eKg1f6R18Ap@RewBQG4lgkt1@x@PnecGKuLu8CzTX87kkOMmRR9J18ugwdXsXfnUVehxF1S1NF86tMILVaLa7u5WZxzPfFwjdFabPCgPuXgiHvBPevNRzbWwoCZPuG3rDnfZo6Ehfm6rrfOl4I0ICT8Vex7evVAi5kfrMbB5m9C8rfMPLUgTZQB@LAIF1hffdeZwARtGwXqq@3nDrgzRFu2AZus9Xq1qxuYG6zV9EU5ZtqOQP675v6AtQ8@kr1IPb7MXfSmXSp9DUgZ8eEeNisN2FNv@MaBHGy4TiCmGtvq4OiKhgi2ZJdbdHRB7hRPBnDDNzSjCBN4Dwe3ufzeik7E07i@iqAraCIvwtugtuuNCYNU2uLwMoSfX9PH36ZH7PH3Audol3HLvrx0cZKtmPzc504qtTsrPeH/GPq0B0IuA/dD@oxzboJqKiATb0XlN@Bk2RysencVJ1W@THZd8fwqqYn9uY@THXRf2bAqz1FpJswKJAFAM2wt6htP4gGrvn@17/vOW5FfREqOZZNsKH6KrrCaWNxoM0@2eU6pad1nUe3JMQxG@CiJpYeyKZpcyZboPWINxHMxJuFRsJxTnCc9eCmiqpgiwq7UXE8QpcZy240m5qeJtpi4RS8zrWqlKApk7FKz@SeNTCDMG9VBZE4P6y3qyCEYKploDD2/HSR7om45tZDwojOVTRtRPbhkJL/@ve2SwYkyihCGF4VTzyytkqkcRwhfhCCoE2A6hWSpWhoDogHmQxqYILmDAi1aMd7aWHAE18RkMTAylMCi7G9JbLpOh3I0270KMT91xNZ8hyma@ete/Yx9Rt6zIj/7Y8Z7xeHb64fAnHOdPnpFcjJC8rVdjILyZtUN@06nLucaqHvGnHVWguV44jqwTBprpXnw5i4vRG5E2fE84FsKKqo5dCfTDWhf8Ctl6C2O03q0DOxx85A3aKj6HYJwxEPIdtRjngQ4S4@Zjmc07/QA5SVgEBzURbubIYo6DgyTmVWOybh7U0tJid2J2SJdxoKhsIpUp3Dp9TpGQkZYk9DP677nx7mITbwMI/nHxlzxZyHh/kPbOgWuKcZkOtHBjtQvpz7chg8Y3/5xYTJrMv14j6xN/mglx9@qRar@Xoj3WjWgZsvdmUPCpox5jeaAmVBV3gBuo9CHOSALYYsmt/WHmsNsr4DcI@HPuTpU3Sh9XrXCWtQh9WugOvQDq5BYLjbzv2N7Pvym@JW@lsARzNJMu1oUbpKBMmRGbe5rUH9K9nCdsHuPgGdveII7tvuUYWERy46BVwKAJe@k0f021raLfiJREAzfptRX8exDwXwagPxFgCZtC4L62un25XbW/mXf4Ya6zCu/VNrTHB8tcYI8bUaA@AmG8lRSBdLzVp@NxOI08YbGuwJA53ZJdK3bL9KW7o0x4dvpZlg4BnYbjm8stGtJj2VTbmriETeJBwZFFAu2B3JTo@J2oVGRRak04oJmrzXA9XUXVio2UClB8nevr3BH1Bp1wEwK7geaP20i0JYM/XWlws01wwmgsLPduZDAkcwm9Qe39MHkfndv/53tr/pgwXhP3XCEoT/lR3@iUEGvfWZs2lcswbZ0ipWaROGS7viY36@VSccsXBElNWJSMtj4OCUMATBbWI39d3g8dy3gJ/QCMBMVL2obUl5ovHoQY@nY4ZBAwNnckGyPyzOoR1AWRMHqOcJ@v/CAMHEorEIxwCRgekKYUC2EQZ0G6HXewyyRk1lPfVzV6BPT09plynwipiKndiMZA75n8Kun9eEHgIsZdsi9zTkgSybHJB25mTzHPI@zotZscu5OTf9eAJmht0uMFJ5SABAvBitOvxwwVCoOayCRlfFuUXU@WJlY4GBoxJHFtH2Al8hCgAiGze6qb6W3c3GI7pjbElzcLsZXG0EqyPYsWuf6Nz/RD9YD@qj461Mg8D8hz2CpEL4z/a4MK@lJ/3Wedbz2vUVa0N/rqsabkUXgFraE2JCYYaLebd6istBBfRiv/gFUEJPgJ4liPJQ0810Nl@8rFTrb5w/CaT7NZibdp@d@h4CQf/94zrgfiX1K6ZmCkz9OlNYsXKbqs2aDkJsFnZek7mvtNeUvlN62971fVs2SXhTEMd@L2IyoQoUyNrnW@ybVGYLMGvvSr0p1eP98nL/eHr2oB68Kf6XfX7xB8EjFC4IPZjEK95N79E5xdVedgMfWjKDK7eokGvz1Mfa6cu@30S/7765fgRq48O52jVH/83QGdMTp4w6URQq@M5@OtQ9yNhFEQdGm7AVvaBrVqRySOqmQIF6sy63TQ3t1OXt01qOH9uaSRV7ekr803kVZiaGLNjQJlHQ9iSWOFPDNKZobWY@MJvCWTeZ4C3IZAZUxXqPryeTBQbeWDnYrVPq4lgONFb0oOLY@GSCIkNfwwHUTZG7J3zqfk6vvcK@5q4ZNHVFtjzoJzkP4iQRauPxYgW4U0VEN8vT5KPj00mvXC99xHuzOgF@VTWd3kzMc@IqVIO5GZ2bAHIQA5G@nIwBTiKXmoijhEiXtQBkBj66V0TcQykepw7BcS8KpQcH4rwn92Gk8Xj9oJJ@4LiN3yfv9cGE2g162GbVOW5ebjPmV/mqbnGMv@eDstoT5x58LuH4EbkD8e5Ze@r2ut7IAHGYdbxne689Z1fKgrecXrvxOn2lEJLJtSLY7TvJZHBgUui1B/MKKLFuGSUIwhjqkca8TnsmxPXYpIM0ufU8eFS/aRleOnCG49mMVmmfj8xI4EISgjTJKZGQrOBqnAcf2PEwKWhnjDXVHl6Wsk7fc8HgI4RJIV76ENcUsmBu4GzcS4HBCVmOCVoYgOHvGCmawdwLKbKvh6RYChcEDIDam0w6cn9AOiDwgtSaPvuR3miDTQ@0uZpMHjutsasOkzSIxekejQFo96i5lcUJ/HVcr4BrqMQAKgtTTRkUyucrUVWhv3pAZsbQO2l@AkJmeP2rp0X9mweRSAkHNokXji8XELr7gFLe/UXRwJ45ZE7IvPbkBcb9nx9w4JecoX/B/BETZE6@eA6V1IIBY8x75jkcpDhf@MjnO1SPPIcqmiM//ojT4ZdDsHaegq6gaw5AgUPFewLyDNZR6lA9OeRPPYe9VOiI5IBbn8/7BTL8xmSCXw75F@bwR7Am/BBj2L3Tc2h6sTuwwSD3AvRhDzlk/CAzXzwu2kWe9cTiD2WfD2kIHj4hAb9hHuo@Mq481Bky8z5xjFymP16pkV1bZd0Sb55dtRnoRB@vNXqU@OTai/ZPK@Dt55P2pO2zj/7whwMuBpOoT7GwR/sUCn88OqAPPruYI5fh@vKQm7rveSkUfH6sjqrVW@@DByTSfZCtuLiIi/6Jpo8Y6oA5Yn@JM8zPP/8M1id9fxY8Cz567wPux3vP/CweP/LHEkf@z27OnkTDhIzjvJ5QyMvQD3X6Ic7zR75I6LN6IsuybvZ68NUG@LQcWGIplJIP8PFwVbc7GnbXf0Jv@U@fPsIf@YfP@hZ/P5IYJ5qAvP189NKe5zl1cDb/7s8TfCsZEmwxHBd6UD/gk8uxj58/QJ1FH/kcH38mExnaFU@4NO0zQtODA46L0toBDH1zke7S83kAP9SBcLCEJO5gQf6eMMxxDb7Bz@Gni3/zmoV/89YI/6iD36RSvu/8zNehYPBpFaIOfj79OfVP@FAHMP84ODt7fHnxBe6DP534Tk7wi//Qd1fBE/KxQ1D8oy/gO70/PQ2enc3PAo9n99TBF@pg/kIdhFwgaA9H1EFqflojNN7nzhxqn50pdQnCp4HH@2oJzOaGP3QaOAgV0ll/qN7MHHBwF93cYmIYb2v5dK7SBOhqKZ@u58@LrXyzCvHm49PZ58@@IDTA5@DZI1Ay/8F35ktZlkXfPR0F6a9@nvaE7FvqIHc2bzKBUyC25MTUSDGBB7h78EJhv1AH9wf3nk@hTyFWYacsN@JG11pl81@pQLw8Z4eawQ7YAdcDeZizYpNdsIs5O9YqXA@CIvyxYwjKrDRn@6zKqhy3g@f9/3FFu65ogEqDbNactRArK8G1X6lcAzIJCh7Cn8yy7BwInLNT@GeVz5VYJcIQCeV@emJJpb3swwN1T7t@FqHnBzl3kHUHY263/BiN6c9fXkKx53tiF0STj/fiXLYeXbTf/fRwn0wm3Y8nB4z58MDYytAVirhOEOTl5ekpl26kn54YXCaZnx76PvsCn@GTOvOdOpdPB70zZG3w9OMD5fbM2u02ftuz6cwOkYAd114nbt@QAHym7@TdDcz3C4PHcx99/PLi9Xo/PLhP3HZNPB5aBGvX4@Ie5iGJDrm8xAxOwhjChdFSiUW9Z2exKNzHEt6AhyXJdpYHl67rD64gmVYHif9GKpU2DH5BgCIwjD24eOPpwXUfekylklESHQ0kY7RmBJJhr8vr/Yk7PXXKCHkh2uWeuzTDTX952f7zfHk59ZCPF/@8Xox0fs@8Hkj2RuFu/sUzP/WcejAOojDXl5czDBK4LxC693gfvS8vdhz8erynNs4zL/AO1w7@Gf81kzZ12n3wcoDmh0pHol5PdyF6IzFPwpd0/lIfoQIeV9gdhnq53Lz7/v7zUfgoHrn/9Hj0eOQ5PQoePZw97ih3r/uABlleyV6KO0C@UQfBk5qLC7ncKIsnuAmgKWJQ0fp0OHmyKwzuJ8/R60@CS/qOfJ/vj5JJu@yjo18@QrcBdFCYCz4HIL@0hz49O10L1Qal9wy@X2iHyRB@@QJyZqeBNeNxlvkfHuYs6Y9e@qSbOvxywL@cEPz0i8t9siOvBL/HfUL2gVxfXIe8cc89ul5ch1@6L2j2HXFeYl1EIycnRxE7HE9AmDvy2kubURbuVmFIEU1eID335ADFyQ0890KtUl2xL6tg6u0wyReNRpkQ/M5/iOVDc@oE90vszRlXwGV3IDqRJPgOaNNMUjCz6ELLz@g4C8OnovAGrUnSRzsepkh0VxTBShUVBRf6cAYBhrTSm8Gs9SN1AIoGrBVThM@4yosTUZxNJjNx/cnK5jE/pD1DmAHj5/e//as/ge/fw/fP7euf/x/JKP7@/rf/8//2u7/5W4j8L/D9v@H7n3//23/7x/aX3P8DfP@frbh/cL5bcPaXAlz/w@9/@xd/9/vf/qu/hu//6nz/@vX3d3/5n@z//9f5w@Df/u4v/wF/nJs/@XNA91d/9rt/@y@Byr/E8L@AMPw70X8KQdoXsD@@rXT6l0MWzDD64ZdN5J/SvzAc6H2aWUcC1n//ywP6unE25ArnLwzLQbQN@We//@2/@TuI3YH8l6vsn2mIew3pSMSqoD8FyL/ZodOB/FMqTjer8FMrnl80tq6NfDp7QcXoTKWce3WJOkBRupQvNNa3cTt1lTW6RtHJl0qvb51LR5vQAo8SJtI8bethHibBeJZIEPstRZ19CZxSZ/V8A5IbFTqRgHj7fo734RDeU2fVJkYUy/SCpN/itVq9MV0uDW4DLxSFneEjHY37/cFgEH7w6icfcg0e/rQC4d43Uw6oa1yrTXL21rmMOSBkiEncLIQ@NFPJXm0Xn26f6O9HwgWjMGjI/QHMEGfaGsA0TRg916Ppm7G1TV1Anx3j85x4loCFkwRZolkqiD08FEomoolkOJTwJ5KJSJSLRaN@LuTn4ol4kvXD9CDBxRLRJOdPRJLhSCSS9NNcKJqMw2RS7ckSw4DByLlcNAnIqoAPMJ3ik2BacHBGHfRECWboH@i5p@f9cNBbRdCTBO0KJx5Y2sUwLo7CvZSjecoVCgN2OszSHO2iXEtaoA/YbCLMgm3axZtMIp6OhV2uJ5ICnyzrcvXwJs4mCpm4yyXiTTTBsvGMyyXhTaGQZQsFl6ti3@DH5VqsblgWChrgXT7Goh@pS8abbNqGG@JNKIFFuVwjO8W@Ga9u4gCm4k04jAhol@t5jQ6RG3ZRCZLLsm9YNpN1uSZ2LRLw53I1CL4w/CUgU9pOipAKZkgSi7cuV9a@iRB05ysMeJPHm4RzU7BTEBDQKXDXVXhh5HL1Idg3QFW7YMosEDECuYcQulipFu9yCXAjLHgV8kkDS1ymF@l@Bj7ZzFN/3u/PzwVMkRuT/s4nX3BShq9T8ENSRo3JfH/KeDHpr5LmFedjYIraXbz9LDHl@d0UZSulsqj0Kg38kJR@f5XQr6w/JGXvB1MkzQGzJ58aXJ8kMElcGwQkhVyV@dx1AjJNYe@iFx7vF2J3e2hTXorQ@z2sfwLGZvTTJOGKxV3HR3B1fXKFITj30KwbzAeX@8Hl8t4nHz@54lHXMcyxA@4fuU8wkU26jl3xuIv2nrhC0DWjLleMDoHQ38GIK/YDbvqT68QQrYmh0qGTF6RgmWJPCCX0swevvB9/u94vDlj35AUX8YDMZ8/S5/PD1/sJKQarGSYC3uMF2Cnekxfo3ozT0SFAcach0KOYM2Uv/gE0iO0awNYwaxVBwwQhGKThC3NtTNdTNjs8rqSHBstAkuH3wUUMJ3tJxuN2x0Nut9d9Akg@0q4tveo9ISTTNms9K/64gCPAnyTY@Q4TPMkAWKF0IAkVeEOSMTo2Ld7ANTpS4jHtiiVdGI2HWyVXhX32Bzj/8VE3enr231G2VRTjqIMXqofPP0WS9EnyBKfQYK6fnjl5ruhFvO@72CL5hDp0I9Hu8M4E5oD8HuLYexAIaxHt4PDwEOb1jTNX2FUJPp0yzvz7jCET74ezk0gqi6sHMDQHH54@@n7tJ4h5g59XawdnuEDy5hOJUIaIviQ9PB3LnkslosjVPm0eAJYT3z/mAwVTKUBKnaC57TrQsdMIygIXaOgHu5qnvzkgky26@mW1tz9RyfbD8TU2On9cJw@o3j/S3t@UZeVLIhw4I4t1KKU0NPNLPflT/KfET9fNSrNS@MweJ44TDw9OW/o5N@cm7fT0GYYxuZanDsxfvFqU@416eXJwrLvDEXeYph9SB3a1ubj34CwUD5r84uDRcYnzROIoqHBPTO8QRx9I7d3PbOdmOibrKFBU4o96/b4c@qPrn385ZBi3m6a5w9hvAqf2/yn80NmKXYgrFnV50VnQ/Onpp6cDGkxo2hWKYkfwMbRtJG@b9J75kfrTkQp/4pFJ/kSR3KpHp2cQZUKEcy8ihOg9YhjmJgQWQDIZS8QOqD8wzNc22iB1vfIsiaJhTsb7lp7ThnzN47K8ul5@hsD1ZCkacF2dV7UyFWi0FXBvBY2F7TjHftiKIse87cYtTAbdezAWbDY8EIycE0hLqF08OEm0iJsGfYSH7KEXo5f6Qn0AXBPBIp5B8HNCUR/QRQVvPSs4P/2jaXlx@571Uh8@ONrStIKm9YTIMZMTGeBOKDAZgT18r2fSuCtAduNt10ceHT403fbSVxa0nckkw4Ft9hCvRSx3i@AjWrKpgNoc0aREQjlWzi7@gw3WnUhISqFYykMeOkVLZHfJye0yunicCqneR8nrFE6zEIVYEJxwioAjIKCDSA/B7R2jf6XgIZA@msN0iexSARRYgX5CiZ@WnIz3ePsI2RG9JCiaCYjt0j12DeijJ6dYpw6rQQgrASzE2hHVTkYqoy/4ndbD59bvH730l5UXlwdT6VM6tHEzc3BBY9gnIZKMwrhnCw45p8ZhM8HGPfqhaU9sbyDPGs6J2TDqhTqy/OMTu6n0E@rKI3i/4C7GyW/GP/4o/KTfjx9PvOOUhVefbwwjzcgj2yBHVmqcAvHQ7@XHE@ve55MfU2PvlQfvYRCDofmFkmxmm16nblBzNQW04E6n6fUv79XAb9RHf@Fe9QHJE//RXWrp51Osfw5fOcX5Ff9zinPqAWVaqaVPPeFP4YsbKjueVjDq@viTnSjMMvIoqeU9/5gCfiiQ0ecrQGWATvNe8fkevVC4AolvM54oP/7I@5Sz@YkSCHgR6qfwp8K9BYFHXwrvjz386fzT8n4C@Y89cE1BMYoXiId8Dq9f1rQDfSfAY7tNN6TbNM6RvDmQN06lju4@Hd0dpT5@XN7PA@NHv83@Y3YjDUj8HIk/2fJk8xzdeelXLCELNx7XD/LxD8Ejk3b5ZbCCju78@lZOm8KjO0jRYfBzqH5BfUkOaFtt1qGEOd5X9nk25EQMMlEl58iZ5OxMq4d@qJA3bQqy7IDbDsS6DFM8Hh@W8NOqpgZ4AoFpzoGRmPgw//SJWhXtuAZByahcujgzhqkiOS/MwFUkcvio/fjDt/TrPjW80rnreVu9eJenYY4Yjm11V6KaSIczDeEeQVANfGFfTmyNZTuEgbIh2gNgiPZAuABqEWSSoyccyJSTCK21aiDIhXpCsl398UAVE/UTqLdNzwcVYpMBnXkPGbJ/mCK6CeRJhhAtn5LyIABdhfoAlUAasA7yI30Gioz@8UfauT1Nwcw0jmMBgiHc0Mch0BtKofDvoBRwIJVDkFHUh6QQoO0DpqAb405BkX9aQY4Xsgcy@IZ@2xk5SJyRPRPVtH3wkW9emwxsiw8fhr5UxCEI/omlDfkh7eUPB85wfwzGynW12cjXrtN1@IUZQ2JzJuXx@vTCN2eW6XgWWVdWidOewNc4sXMpgAkDlh@IlNbDs0l79GWzRIdC5ZwfH1MF1h/YSz8woB6vMYkmOfzHDGpGn5nJI5nZPb0Yz5Ek/oHkrOTA6lBJJIcMzsrmyYDNgwEmLtPAYO48W7dzrO1YNE3nKLbA6nRbcoIveUZijK7@0Audo9uI68Vq95j4KuACqp94wBhyXyZHlg5sBDv5ySlblp2d9A8Kj1zr8RaPEk0lYY5/TLN@DHCrQGgVCK8CkVUgugrEVoH4KpBYBZJOgFth5mzMMLELh2ObYHwTTGyCyXUwwm6CGwyR0CYY3gQjm2B0E9yUFlmXFksQvPTBipuk64oGpnGRxCoNn@xRLRIZBTTc68gIEBp6AwnZI28iobzEbmQ8yToFFZkKAoVCsc09aJ8VbMpjU@W36fDbJdt3TiSMVZQ90yECmzcM0Er5OZ4xCULnPabR05miQO3SgiLyYAyIFlgpqQLIv@g9tp8AMhbHG29nxJDi1veQHc9ggzwcOS7VFp89yaF9yTa20F5s9iNU9JoxW67iDpE2lcc7I62NMbITt431IypY5Og7ECEbAttg17d8VWbDmOwtMvz1IncQ7i3yDVE23ui@XMgbD0GeWmUl4z/BllqVZ9spImltMAOcs7GJDLxqUHwULPWFO3b9/rd//b/Tv//tX/wt/bu/@dv/7z//Txj@T/jzf4LNQofWAH/@F/jz7/Hnf8Gfv8Gfv9zKRODDx67f/fV/gNv/8T/Sv/uTv7CT/s3fufyRNSJIwahNzr/6F/jzL/Hn/3L5o2vAv/ozGxCzuPwv1I5p5QGoP/8vNA2lIZY1sr/@e5p2@cDA8DiSd2/38cetB0dsBGs23JPQ4@t0@1cYGMh21utzAV7njtvc@bABvFvIDR4Pe970PTBnbIdF1NICLwzw4QAnSjPR/hHQhNHMYB/kbdYDo8dZInBD7f97@ph2@xAGoskTcClbhzv1d@rt2qQirM/FAHV4fqKDCsPeNSUwvaVAvslMYGEGcdpCZqScLSMOf8t4mPxqAHGtJEu2PJyXcspa5YZJD@2cyQv/m6kuCi0OQ/YTZORsbMrxc@e2CtxRN6@aDUp5HQNTxs0zJdtZSYQ41qFJINua38hYvCFc8L9Gt2k5p9vkK4VXHQY/XTAxR9saaV1Qina5vgGLnHbgvWhxhXfhbXodgHv2OPy484TKPmDX7e2ti9qKY1GGjJ6HYNiqlK0y1kncblJoKym0lQQ02ziJromGQq9oIAMH6sXdp7HsbFsqajfbRriw56zaAcmAuaC9KOiXlIk5SL1FTTTyrrJ7i3wLJfeYcvrJg0p0zhnt8r7JADh386Ret@V@1OwbmLcNtT8ncnsnZqe13se0k2erUxDuUa@5tG45Lrmv5XYL/Apq7tH3nQWF2H9iQYHvLCgW/XZBr5sV8@6gf5@/31Y7KzWx1vAbZHbHP9gZoHBo/GsQvY06QooNEvR4YcqTdqY83ZlGe/YcvgzxzOpcip0Tl42t0ypwElPWLNFeHvisazDl0NAK3npjw77XqzgvSOirmiGa20@eybYXv@rGZx8Fra/CqObH8zFk5zhx3Di2n3LfHVfWI5tjhWbtl0AgaptRaHk@PcmqbD09gfGpSN4NA/E2KKBrtZvCt0dAaCu/Z23aVnSPhuf8WN5v4yT2rp2tIQsjT0V3Et1QSJqGCZ0gKjD5oge8MML3oBCWYBXJc2BokXYtjxeZONDGWl9UNXzsE3O/Ql/c4EaCeF0ntPhp3k8LWxQ5k2iP4Oe9TtarX52Vvgp5eO86f2gXwQ4z/LTxmsfIWWNPcU/vFmdnW5VX//X01rfprX@dXkk2TOs1zSQSV3vw@uuKDns2GABwQ0b422T4nSe935CzQ8o6Gg81tzN8N4k90RRg@ENK0wCadsCDEsiHf31nwt2a8NZ7/P96A66y57@3@YgxW1@Avhnn0fYjUzSTnHOhCqIHwIte1D1vi1uLdu47y3ImOmSG56ddRHGp6KEPHVPXRdVcb9WuEH9D5tGj5Y3cEzeXlJ24hyZj6qdHofebKPfUExV@IfY8DqR/C@@qxjWR7xF99X0VR0VHlJ5mn2TvYf3cjilGnqQiQMfviAzvn3q974uVDSKvpYdsxhEKi@/zjyzcvVbNuAiasvdANAM06AE5QoEcXKEv9IX99KViv0DH0aP2@GO3ZBkfSv0mQ4AP9utROP@mWO/X1GfNs67Sd4wIa9jgbpXxAasVRnzE6W0b/joWfbumZJVhnSm1auUd6@S9Fpe/1uJbUrGSSdsq@T6R/JbQfbfMbYmajWyjwrK/bgh5gznLK4ogeLYx2jFfbTFNfaMTMA5bTFPfGVWe9ijUdU6i6Sw8pzhl2xdeSoZgEa5TuLbgighhDvpkC9SqbmjXrpa8SMqY17esFifmXkBbdIuL3u19xC0oahXGhdyXdZnCu2UKb8oUdspc94DdIreAKGGnSKcVsHm@1gSKKFnvaGdMwpk7XL6mtuGjaryBe69f3LL7WPbT7qn7GBSyW3Qf5z2glN0993GOBEz3cZ0ERu7jKwhs@pb7F/fxqlsggAG3JPAZ4x0VjveC@zjr8b5Q5LVpq3KD7uN1mwLMJ/uWcOTFXl7tOrv@2npVVRT9tlHpp1FiTLhoWK37Rz/5svBPQJ1ziSDxY4oOHRFgnIDsDBpbI4ZdDgwbQfJeJs@@4eN4tTTlrG9s1lAg3ZfaWlRBKZkQfeQ@cO8qI5swTCWLj3AFAlFvHu@niObezMy@RY5TOkgoaeTd8gn3gsQe6HlI@j0Aby/iKJv8q/baRWE34PfRiZnfo/MNOaviCEXoDODdQxYy9Wf3VyqFbf3qjBu79bdb6O0aATZiYAVitxJBu6XTwYZD25QUpmv6rpCQVNztk7fz4MfplCi9r7IRreD0zHeSSbRTM1QM253f@7XqbOVD0nZUECbes492L1uPC0QXY9JG121ZqnbnAxK2dE6PPJ4uotjmnCCBs9WNn4wV7w1Dq7x2kURz7apJyBzER34mvGWXvtmXwQeBft30dZUTTHCgERFs5VyXYutX7VfY75ptv68M6hUTXhWwz7DeP5S@Na@/Osq@olzZFPu2ATHRT@e8e42jdQkblsPsYMsy/5qsvTHx8cUVtpFvF7rG/sraX7FtPSf4Bt9ezy1sXGglGNPdyBEuzI5C7zPqrUWiTIMroyWIJTl47IqvKd1U7eu02hXf18SYgmM0XH51Axu7DbzdeIiPVMB4xXK7l@OLvsg@xbpv45r61s6FveugoZfY@sSmrUhQ98R/be2iBRGVp1quUi51YNCNx@Pet1sR2Gsh72Ycp766TbCetoT8eDwHef0o@k4MNMP6@KC63rqUkQgwBniyb2OLn9PHvY4u29Lnr/ou5LNhtzjq4BptugG/o5XQ1OFxyJYdvlrAENHyHPEOkpV5C/z2k9ka7hqhdOCGztMTGb6entA55@nJGcWwadbbSH84cF7OE9p6h@jBrjfTO@9vxgWAydh@g6WzAOc83W77oRzg22LXb39e55qolrxydsD1IdyiWntGeMKc137J7CrGfhcsSKonFMEpbCiKT1DauRAaFz6Ja6VTzkfb0MGjG01dU52XxY7sFwqTgyTN1dIrIXuiznjiBmKXQh783KLIdsha7YuR9z@SU2ztl23yqr2EvOKNnxb7QbLjE0rClGMk6/bpTWvXD9NLMhGCiY8W8LiriGN8ByPI7p7V5GsZWmVQkPt9ECTGOQ/YdnBp4GsZA5oUyG7eqN0ib9J0Tr1zfMLIiZPOOjCw07NzrIRJh2JgTSX9wNnNFxiLbjI0Hh3BEictAgXfOFzidjDh38r70bPw7l651ceL@D56nrBl7WfMZGgdBURe3eKz8@jZ1tK0s2lJ9MDWzuXqhBTKOdEmRfYpg@ijpntcB67VuTEYtN0meEVYHbjgwaM@jqkPKlE86AFGC7ZvDRi4KhptZHvNu3ZJVekf6HCIvMYMyiNWKikWcNg7ezvYIQ2yIrG2d5@jYFw/9Fw/4GYi9eEAdaEta5h/JcoYJuffbWSZ/uigszdUsCvbXWB1E926CcNU48Oegj96XD7A4nN5XTuYAN7Z/fhga963WUEpev/ANHqxdkFLp9ONMWfUztP99CBd68B9hi352sNInmHyF0ovnSt2F@davDGVQmyjc5Pphn3VeG@uyxfj7IWep@RIZ@y7C8@TF5FlNBvOpgX2VjovSZF49la6NcW0IiaZ6XB00xNrepczTPmqfF2uLZlC86bVvxlKd@32MK7WKb12l@nfzMWbRFudtprJonkjtrJla1QeWhNuUYm3Y82ZamZajczgclGcjebFmNaRo9kbMd6S9IuZsIjqwkWTups2BrH6xWKU5Ma9RTpr9jpxn4/pZDP9xIXQu5Mu69mrXt@IdqOjepIPT8eXkr4YXF2oz6Vhtj4VfPqwUIxNKbVanM7ESHvUVS7Uu1qr1c1lqrMRZ97pvWGkfT2xugkjFg5P0uJgGIkWJ5aRKGXSV3Erly62Cspty7pbtBJVyrqwGvHmpZBUfNOKJYQnuSZjsq35pXxVn8UuQg3tQr1UisPq6HxyXlX0ySgXkSuNccTo3xa6Wih0cVOfXnRKlBG5bHcStWEokRPmAnMV1bRxuJEsl4zr@STzXBHbWaGeEbsxNhO9zXPD68pCqExLtVq7qreb47h5xSl3BXZIVW6FejozKpTGCa5RXhQT58X6JJstzqfdkNTX0pNeO3x9G5uVymKxfcOEL/iJde2TsxWFGV5emotW86p4WzbvoFtfX8oRaTHPtDKG9JzLmte1ElM2RoN6ZKj29FZczmrCZbUYsYqj9MWsfZcsZkaiVO2OtFGjrbQnlpwbMgVqkR3dNLvirCAvZ3w@UmrdMMN8TbDi6X64zgwlqTtSKuayf15a9uuTbr@XrJyzOfH5qpdpRWt5nbsumJGyuqA6jYwkL2s3EjeqJi@Kd918Wr5Wo9mqqFfPL6bzUKgjS9VZdMnNb4eFiDwXImypkrm99t1chmq@ki@TqWrhSp8K5Qrn7X70yqcVxCVTkvjneNZnTCaReW6Cb90sNVXFGEcVNlFo@AZx02gnr69nXbN4W8u2BWWZuLsejWJ3Nep2WjQ1I5S4LKSTTHXEGuf8sFy8i8tqITLLnCv5ZLG9bCasfGmiJC5K/dxlzcg1xsJtMt@vLxajfuJSrJZGaUpM5Gq1Ybff6s47dbO6YK8jwrDry5/ny8996MeteiF02czE@pNauHWVU6fVRsG31G7bJT1bHnH5amISa8TDY2o6v0yk65Yq67nz62TsZiKX8ulcv5nlNFG8fRauuBFfbyzYhBk3bgq3N7rpsxpdLdIdZMKLm@sO07ozzeiFTN3N27FiemQIV725dWnGG2pIq9yw3I1UbirRaVt@7lS1YXrMXDVvl0x3tizMq5Zg1UdatBePjs7n5rOxvDKuqERnyCvNclYrDYXYVUdexpkopzY6Wela6FyG2HSzf3EtFi6m/WVTHIeGF8@TC4EXzGq60z1XYtO57pPCiWmJapTbt/348zPbFcudpJweNWvVohVq8MykUy9Fn0sd0ywIzaKcicjqJJfpnI/G2bsF3zDny0kj1lWkRdUIsXlqXu5ct4Sh1jcL5p0wXN4W7tTrSSh2WxlKcas34sYyV2pJbLys13w5X1U57/YXsdZEnApgGeo3RZ3LpIfDClXhxvFpZpE0LfXcvCp3s5dpOZ0uJUI3eih@McqeX8x7cqvZKl/0eC1y182GY5Vunw31MuV8vxoZ9@PVcjxSylKN7uKmxvVyCZkb8Ep2eLmI6MlSKBNjWrPaxc2wMVDLSjbdnkuZsNDQZvE2L6lNcRmLM9esbzhIXqppNlKNUU0rZzVLhVnYp14Vr0PVxUK47fKTMC89d0yf0FkOlpWWyGvKoPRc4xqtSSkrD4etWEZosJVMnZ0szRmvl6pUMldVuVxpPi3MBvU2a@q5Cz3RnZd72WpV7Oq9sC51K@m5xE7b7bubm2ZFHd/ejC9q8W5l2eOH0ZYl1WKVuUU9g8nTmpaahe48J5nSsDZ9Vs/nk9sWE2mej0vN3tQ3TN51pmH5tsKWypmWxE@KN/241SzP9etLRVKYcajSZ6hZs7pcWmJay5dn15251Fou03LGfObmVwxfOi/mbi1fMl9I5yqNOm8olcp5KZfmx7PrWek27hOX9eteVB4931FVVVVCxl1diWfYsBlqRnPLrDA8ZyfnmXHjspHkdK550bq@vuIGijAW4p1KLta@Ftrp9OXV4lLiW9WqXr1qNqiKT729u2swlYZSSkqlYq2hRYtT47rdjvMzLX3Ds8XIuDsrzTOz68mkPU5e@jqWyIe1pShytZlSYsQLkJ0EJU6m1Wy5ai5Cz8vhc3@a025bybR@HktnF1JvKk6XbDo39TFmYT7rxWQ9EWp05udSR7ju969qmUFYn@qNWDZKXSala7XVzQ6ukwvx6qLUKkwssd7rRmSfyerDxk26aTaFhXwuxAbTptlRoPNJerSRySZN5S6XuDJkH5sQMpTQvuarTGkQvS1f9rRZdn7dWuRgypHgpCob1RZqa5IYqRdXZuaq/XyVSPSb3YsRFDwZ3A0EuenL9LrijaSUqbvbq9YoX520mOHN7XW82rzwJZZh4/xZ0AbnfHLRWFZYVpSS/WlxMg/rJSFxnriqCMrlvFxrSmI/Vg/dKOfqksqp8QGblrjZdKYyvkU0k8j3pUyzrBq5pnARF7UqzzDz9p1Vad8mrkLn7A1bH8/YkHk9Y1ipo8qLTrnTCfWozNS80tt1bpr3XVjpTn1YE84VptyuFZfaopQPmc10OStdTWYLvbSQjfCdUDrPKlVB5sAsicb6DaM5WmamXaotzUvZTCJ@F7oACTJNJTnrRHhRMPX@fMiUricXynw4GbUM33jO1Hx3nXk0OWgNTEYolRrl4ixvRLVLc6hSsZgQumgbetysPY8XxayVG7SaSiSbbPW7lYsOc92QrpI32fpdXIxWmeKzmGzXY6xQirYFhqtp46kFI5LQH1GlBdszBEU0@Pik8hzNTya@3mI6sXz6Xfz8KtHuj7LcVOB94XRXe@bnrUuFlctxsW9W2rPpbaENFqLamjZVqnDX1MNX8oVUv2hVrkdcNV1bWkwm2RZuI/2OwUmqNK2FrehlUezHBSmXvxsNcxfF5yLbkZ7ZGacYNzfhwgVHxSVfxtJ6CtO60W/UZYgX051K4nrWW2bHg7IkXhRDOaNTi/XqV7ySh2FUfi6xeqtwXrrrdZUBI2lqpV5jWeouFsq3b2vP3LR3U102tPmF0b9MV5XwrVRUtepti8vdGEw5nincZIe1u@wiEasaSlds9BMNdew7D2sCn1ZLMSouTsVMq800RTnMxefLLj8SGe6uPRolLphlzFwyadWcDRP9ZbJ7Pubad2XtvLEYMefj@V01c8tNRB/HVQWdurGW1ej5edt3tThvFvtKsygJDD9eDM2LzES8nHVvYmlfQmcbvnyvNZiXqn29nWfi3W6Cq4fD7Yj13KsuzJsy1cqVLsLx3MKaS/nRpDxPXOjpWH0xb95EIqO74bySqMdq0Tk31Ub5jF7oRxnt1oyr88ZFv5AR89K1ZF4vu8KYii0n5WIhkfdFRb5T7dyxUp55rvcUa9CXGle34XqMEaIXlers7i6XZsZxaZgvKucwJs746/miPuyMujcVMyxTWqXjK8aWsWX97qbcU6vty@tBd9aPx6vGRWuYnCw7ek2u@fRls9jVznPVsZJb3oLAxWrJ6LCp5Jtt@TZXYyuUFWunZ2CDc5mSvOgzxSh7Jans5Xx8nrwdt2OjzqiVndY689EwVo9HtYm4jFvt5@hEbMY7l@M6I3Q7s4EvdE5p9eXiNn8TMUrlmV6yqpp4xSZCpbtRc5yfNH3j7FWha2XbrN4NtUuziS8bBasgcd1Khsrdq2GmODq/MS9uQkmqUZAXk8TwPHbuq8JgMhmalURLCSlTps0ordlUHI1ZvpzjW8a82yyUeuVeKMHoPjk@s65iz5ed6h1v6RGVocxFrDfjfRd5sCBycida97UsnR3DXIS9nYav1H44ZKq39bpgZbX4qBlOipGC0VK11lwbtkLyzXl8NBPkqyGVEZe9iNKstXvl@XLWS44iPb4@baYLt2o7nFX1wdw0uFjyKtTin6tjI1yx9GqpKWTUmzHPSzPfXMnkro36lOr1y@leu/A8kaatSCUdSS9ue2xkcjcdcuryNt8JDavd9ECa1dqRZW0WzvTOObU2lvWxEWLYRkvNjxLz5oV4RV0u8@JikLjJVFuR5tUwOQor/VG9yi5GFVkS7u7MCVfs9Es3XK8YbWVukqMLyUyL8WZSuhwy83K3chfL9sQIS/kGxTETypaE8GX@1mddCkr0WV5yZWuZlNRFuSl36/1pWi/1hs1JOXPBZLjQ9HxeGYcvakx4wmfGidyV0TEUSsxH0/Nm5TpmDu7SViuiVUPThH5Xlfu3oV51wAtjNpYAHXzd694tmulaZlbqlC/qZlrtL0WfMbtSz4uFQkalLqR2@dl85jVpko40K6XOzfNN2ug3ol3LLHLzZ5FZLNTKZVYQFp100RyVW5d1tRhnx73Mdfxm0CupTa0qh68oIRkf3cYZtS5cTlgxUk1HCs@tc@G5OI3VtJFqCY38HWeVa6DsitFmRe/MxsvsgJXm4Uj@1qz0e/od9NbhkgpNLmqdXk0aqvNZ7dJqXYXHdW7UmimjmMrrvkg@WanwXD@Mk7DoraaONeWqb93Wy9Mrg2EGy9hE1M/FK5kqhfR@uliLXYb48/NOLtnkxs8lMZS4jkzSs1Cldu1To6KeK/bHCpsd1YbijQxThnasOrxk62W52b@bZG@Tizq17HSlpHrZnmlX2dEsN5oOG815GKZXjVbJNOu1W6tXnIa6l3GlWxn0GrlC9kbI8rwZr6jZfGWkT1rd8ewiEqWGhfDt8Dp@Kfdjo3hRXHSuJnqyerksZgcXEV9HvUxYHd5SnivK8Lnctazuc1xu1W8umXYmLqjs8yJu3Q7ajEldJMb584gYXxYHXLypjqeTSa9SU7XionpzDWyOh8KN8y6T1ts3VavVuxCF24smWPqXmlis317q9fPbi96kp1JKGMQ3yxhX5yWzcJsb3XGzYm3RlTnfqHI1q0TjUSnZ9U2j4/JgkotG2/HxZXlayOlGbH4NWr9fXVRLYq18TXHj605@5LuUOC5hXC9b00gtLd7GutczaRaJ5tJzdZBINNn5zeW5cJPo6sXZuHnJ9W@Y2V1yZI75Jl9LC5pUoTLPeniRm1t5Npq/il3c3ojD2KyXn4SK6Vm9XYxZybLUbkeeZ7XZSCwXOKkxn85C1ULlxlIj0Xnr5m50Ba0QpYT@/CYfF68jYo@Vl3dZo6B11SafZplLJjRrtm58Wl99Lou@UTVUCOuxPDuv8jAzvstMLnuxbnOotM8zF8kB1YsIeV/DjBXvYs@3z9eycTv0xcegchJSbXpzDSZJ12o2IvMbKdnhlq1sos13C0suf8WkIxcXk2QxFLosJUsdyqxHxyAtz7PQ7WVOCd1UW43IxJcr5@a9Qf2uWcvOrhN3HW5cbdenlzgZCzPsTKoMa81FuTBvymIsP6rlpQzlK97MzEpSl2q5Vt5gqj2pEBmOLs4L5@LkSpjM86qP7Rebi@nzZCwmLq8VXjTUQs0apIVwJzEKz4Winn6@alGLCz5/yWUTrYQxkoXLYblpDs1pW5fkdOQ5OvdZtWFVvormao1bddgclMuGkL0OxU0xN6qPY3fN4bw7FfO9S0qyklNBmZ@XY5aaWRTk2@b1zWWvzi6EauKyXDDmbJcpPNfZqcU0E/Vqo98tG3JpCAOnr9PUtIQCKsUaaDcUrw@K7KyVvuol@mb2nE2ULueVplz2sTf52jAXMqeGjxmMK6HcUstfhqVZvF@7uRqzRnbaG/iuqnHmbpjRZmUqavXCbd4cJWsS1@m0GD1fW5rmdaLZ9V3dKIxYC93FMxdLrtEN673JoJPojM@nz53O9XO3Vb@A5rz1ibH69TPVv7m6MONSUuB6zUy2lNamOntpjGtSZFzSOs1QR/J15rni7Dl0xRaGxS5XLg@Wy4xwabTVRG7cvc7yi2Ez0aLC@QrbuwuL@mUz99wpDCZDIVuaC@Fb7cL03UbK88m5kYjHuEhyypvh1njc8iXSiuyLhweLQSiTn8ZyTM@otal8xZdtaxr0gtpdjC8zZqRXViyzGW/U88latpC9KF3lb6VSsl7kb299nZtiNp9uxC6vBqPIVYczM0zmejCsh6hhKTvqMZaVmMh1uWDmz43cfHA3uhlPurP4tGR2luoVP5H7Y07i9VG7pMZj6ZvWc7TChvPXTP5uqaiheHSepHqC1LtklNrotp2Q8xdMRxnABDoH8j@6vZ4YgmSYg2Qban69VOPZZqXfMi6UQRUoVLoTXZDGSXk0EMN3VI2pJwrxtnIlCZVObRzvdOXbxmU4Lk3mMH/t5JZXUo6BVm926oMJexvLg@kaiTwX24PxzbTcMmvRXKtRqkao1nMtJ3HFfKnUurN6XLnC9gtTqxlPXOQ5YZwZlfOLTDdTnBWEZvvCN/SFGj1hWmillXyrx5vzxR2bZI20NKRiw9h1Rspx1izakoxI9nJQCfNKUZtXLhP6uFa9DGUu8zeSNjLYzE169Ym1FsmxHF30pXT6vFXsZPtU@iabG4ZakinUVN@sSMAyBYX/w68@KkQ0DJWAUVNN7tHkLcPOMRcnXzl4gpw8gY@375w7gc4@2wcJSM7z1UALlON3NfEJ4WO7ELK3GcQD1nFr8eT13mKAWx0nQC54jgd9RA5Vl3Y2Ql0GZl6T8VFWv0YA2fEkOyi4D0YeT/7BPIYv0OBfoQQ2kSfqPIQ33m/SRjiC53zguYTs48nWlqeH26YGCYQm41UJ@Ol3/YCnKvwIGckWcL5S8O7b1mdPdvIDcaaukpNGXIGgi2R1TsVATLso7NbE@PXZDBQ5kGW1sfaVV8bwDJdgY0lyvget@i3/@D756D8SUi5atGReHZsTY9Yb9bXBVKIVWh9258Ji@UzT0QgdhrJCP9I@LJOLpRhypmccfhN0knVOdiKfT@SIYjzfipwWiAdTu2k6sD4d6iPtJQE//hy7Tt5IKX00XkmhfcjH@D72mFJT7Mn4Xn08UX0@r@VLWT7O58GIHznviT5xPBHvrUfy1D5zRF@vHq3HA9XR91eT6KqmCgPNbdLkFZ/bz5yQc7xWHWjM69v9aSoKlmZsx0goT/x4pyO@jcJdYv5VTllbwVkLXcStu/WpBAq@HBl/PkxikZO36VjDDx/wCI0Tx3diuwJfKH3SVWThmPpA@Ilb4Pg4/fGxcyiMQKPcfvhA4mQ70qaFlk0PJp@sUgVNXziZZRvkaVWX0y2UZx7cW/X6vwdyBdUFmXzC198YAGaD2OzdAacBNdka9dpUYbgkqut9UDzHx3uCp5zQH1dpqxN/EB7lhpy782TRMjmlBy6ntANKzsCgvc6JEyT2XsaH3ogrwZnbTvownIx1sv8ctOl1OIJv7HvSedlY5wyaE3w1qYfmkBnyimhsAQy84FFqU94St5tm1Rbo@EYevsL6IL4qeUEDECzwhrFA3YgPHyC@nkbyfLBfCemhLc12rLTJcPKSanidpgbG4Ym7bt19TBM/uBOIIluiJ1upQ0jFur6TPIbkMW8N3kkeIO6J@V6yAcn4osh3kmVItp@J3J@uQbq90/8OgIVeniCuT5b2ZPGy4rEP9MCjQF5she2hfb4VY9ciQNsNY7fHbn7aORqF/mi3ji1sO@IF/ZOIlQ2AIu1xOg/eb6SFpOKBxB5bLrbKtHlCf6G/WZjjHAksfiIlgdrF8r1HO/jpLQKg/4Eqpd@mrwq3W3td0R35CcKw08fWBmaF6V9@@RpljiDuyh/3uJI@u4XQD3erhja3Nnjs99ht2tXOtHQy7c/jHB2zrd1WPhKbeqw6ZWijQuy@tenXkqz2oAxA/HE7Gl2evPSnTcy9@Ugfr7XHho92t/g2H0NvpAc9okiP9NPdTVD4fq7yKPeQk4cRubtRFnhOGH/yhp3mGjqwC30G0GtuvpIzYUdmnF76ayv7fbU5APpIpya8ObEVrQCm4ZlD4B7yeLtdt3WCjezQfWzH4/v55F1k8jvI7PP0ngCBdQo04Mi2UuOrMVFWg/YzqaDn2VDET1zMbZCXDZtWyup7@PTP0LmQcc6QPcFXFu2qJHoPa96Ar@uN/Dp73eVeVc/W9Psrd28/1Oz@5EYa6bfyRKTuE4ySxzRLrw9uOqFfvq2H/nGc@bJpvh17x/S8rytWjb6SxO8RwZd3GP1NIdutQuiR3uE4kkA0wzeGJHII4f5BaeNa/7SKWbld2n37XQsMqTrZTUeabYSrBDCUt3P5HZvrbKM6ndMXn6yVcePfWGH4pkBbKsBkP6G21TlO5wpk8N6OXR8dRTiynYJPsqOFaawok6WVbQtm8CpfUHjCZraZjPyEPt3XtJ5nZTA5BgPBsDqhA4D89nFWa7PKNi83xUNxjtFL951TPlbj7gnEfHSiyLgCEWh8OrKJRBz1Sbc5wW6zZd/IJnmRJUnH0QiKWj19gM6Ktvahj1/HI/TaBPqwN9NK4@OZZOTkSkfPk5F4Rz24sryKjqHYHPbU@tSF8euGQJgzmGhvzrckbfCyZ5XBPsPTOd3yy/bURT6Rg2gTrxt95QXpPVlTc3rqwmLWAv/yh4OPzMQ0mK6sMqI6BaO6u6AOaFG13990jC/5DiTQURjf0e1oE@KXTZwQQUygpbC0oCrOPM57vPEUUZeXss@kI06LHIWH@BK/cUWc9sDqt09s0TVzTn4XMFlggxPd0kiKUxA5u47@Rf5lc54qS54icmYMDjmnBM8GxoPPF9ixC9tXMsDZBhKHJxR7t1DcY06icF0PLhe2HxLq@JPeP1JmUOSFARKBsveLPZ2C5iKS/EKZq6bHs9aQFfjwCgQV@5QJnfiOYhHEOjEX5B6qj/ccBuwY4uKKcu/MUyjiEIwpiqbpKOToCor5T4EBNuM/1Bu5fK0WdF7AYXuso5e77ceMjwiSA@vIiwTWbrzorY7HBdqN8gEri7jt8lIb5ET/Eh5hsQ6bsCvMkJ02r/A8QrsGAY7cvanGGt5rgxOWkMednDsTeck6p3roYEch7zbZPFvZAqtsK@AtVnz4Jjd4QcCDIK7FsQYUZ0VFAaJtXnzYsOP/L@5YmxLHlp83v@LIlF4yhgCus7s1jq4xBEkVJGwSVGrWayFETQ0Pi8AAtetvv9vd55EEGWdu3Q/3CyTn0a/TfZ453fiIEpH4DxX@9DPivFXE8/zKq/xKId/k@ZyorJQ5fJpnhT7mC5Xe/ZWVe2GlrJjxCtcpA6Zdj7xLmbN5ju6Tt8qmJizSkqzwmWpKrpUq41Mho5LL@feO1uc5e4U6SsFV/meeL/T7SLS8orJQ9ryIH/810UAx@WAQVxa3tNScJuPf@fajyqEelqFbJV4d25vUjhul2BAR3UkFuglQYjLbs9MMymFd9jhkM6WzT@clU2xJ/V7eJoNHjnplWDtsJCclwnlIglvTSAJ4KHsvB4JgoqIxablnsvJGVN7kwGKpPYlWk55CiwYOrG2b@Cl@1v03/khjLxIny73bnfkTp3zNmec3LYoCok53r7RbTMXeZDFfxjxRMPXGKJLh3mxD3N1JeDNcgQ6fsKdQOGN@H@RhtpyO9lQ/ke8oZE/xSu4qR0g6K1CX6vutJsTMF@0/1ffa5WACs8JxvGYWzqkH5M9eK1y2WcTpIgUbiIHBOUuXz8/jRPh1Yyu6zsH5rB99wMsIGcTcpMHUXLwgyssb@CQux0Alk/kIeYX3DLOMdPn4yCOmMwzJCl3rQwIgF6ZmTTc8mDu6QTviV15itkQ/rtgBj2HZlyOCtxy3HhX23tTkxSLO6gO37@kCpkDA@Ix8HqKr1Y@a9scyGX6xL9lRrfZrvfZzPScyuVVdM38@ppjwcookM45q9VrtQ/1Y0@zZ84ZfbSwPdYR1XEGABmvjQH8Fuhl/xZCpmgUjBhVMYeqfxvOv8cjUtCAe0R7w/ZIkgqq8TGPuRZn8vGIKzK3Q3z1MdyepwWDZ9YTdC/7j@Mx91w7JsYah4R2i53g@SRb8ptHsazJCAcp7Uw@z8Xi2oo1ovLLE5YGVJvEChPJeZ0WSyC@toIXmLuQuFqQxEJHdB/ezr@RHWogB5qkJut@nC0AaOlFECHlkPCx0jhLANxwPkgmq0w4C0MtSJgFJALA2Wg7jN2nQiIj/kgYZsn40Gy7RM@9AtkwVer8Z2QqYezxPoPfNBEytQtVytEMDRy03ZKHfjK6twGHw3A38K7fhNNhFn0Uth9l@t08BqljLb0PvEjLLa0CqFwXuRS/yIaFkhVCzRBma5fWZc9MNnDBkfsDcTrftAjQAH1he5DqhwVzPbvdgsL40GEBgnh@xtttxIygW@QZhldW0rB7zm6zjBHYLXq0Lt@1GfcLYdCMPkTUBm8W6VhC5dq9tBazbC7p@6DBkTGu4od223I7TMDHKlecz58rxIha2rHZ7i1H/2nMCJL7A5YUDVFoXbYcwEZ8NN3DsCBnKnmwQHhDYNljYdWwXH5wbB9ixgr4hgIbOHz0oBJmsYXWsS2BOK39HKtAudi9wOkg0SCLsXYSRG/Uih136foNkHTrBlWs74QnT2n5IAuuFjsEwaiChBhggLciH54te6JLcXC@CMaPXjVzf06GRr0EwQKUFVRskYN/j3IKQ/KCPUFEO1AAGu245kB6gTElaFkohBKnZUb4YIAQhRnk2medctt1Lx7MdzPYRzLUbOjo0mBtiAYCJeK8tQNojrrGdgC7@CMqqSc01qDmZ22RW48pFykVp0IDQFdpCYrNbQuZgy1Vt55Hbmwd4r0/5xFbI207ibb/hwIyPB1gpZek9GHR@Kx7eFfJgoFGZ8CpOQWmsuhvF98vHu2T6MMOluarGT7An6aOB0YV0jNn4p/ZG1FhxUE4V3r27u7uy7mCdG97d6caP1CyQ8b0awgvrW6V0weN4NhjRMr@wt5QX1NmB8PVucMfL@b2WA7X5oLNqdRSLanh5EQHLbSIRlACAjbBnpFuNgynLoaQj5uJeEUXM2N4sksebsxR@pn9nL3xsyCVA58y/W6hWcQ1LZGDkE6boByQUFEREBqHvAJIHQmmmcfzlsVzLo8Mlv9ig0mUdKruAZeBjWf9O9fv4cat6Zbs@EYt3TWmyIt3BSzftqJgzehMiY6JdzDlxVuZbe/SnS2oIEUwKdY6KLrKKr0/KB7w6@hfle4X6iXIlTuFAOtaNe42LudrR8clWekulc9vCW@cY2wbGu89U75b@Wre8ABhYgssvEEmy4Ueq1WquDszKaD6pCqOv@icstEpGMKbiUP0U07COHvK5u@B8fRiM58k6Tz10w5eB1bnoNZvQcyK1x799@PWXE0143J8vbgz@30c8GMyRpAuz6FUC0zTKylmJDfOe5qtgObnoPth6WBBjI8pGo8QBTGmV50w@R@DxNfg2ELKbYoSBKQbZKGGQgHmJ4f38eE@T@rrTMoUClAus6sjNZLCmGf4ApkqkA0PuJXO8oVZb4w/CVuYvTVwxJBRIqFg8eV5sQHNhcUH9XqkpHQ7Q2oauFWMRsyT1@Hkgv0HigsE@k7ww4B18ehO6nWtFmNdiQ6O9UrNTTSBib5sKGaSFQi4Biu4slRbMExNIuRH6Bo99ERwIszDUg7UIQYxNVbMig/fwPWdhGALy7dkpNNHBgcL0ieFGqi6I4vv/xdAxeWsgUvgHDWwLsPzySMlZ5dAm9Pm/dPYX11T06o1wToTGinfQ3F3sCCgn0iW6eJcRZBiHlQWUoaSVwqHJIn1ZRImzIKb/SR4E//8okx3wP8GCE6Bn0qJ@OJku4x@UJEHlsoLVKwklWckvxnKfqWXSzCf1MzAv@YZ5UoyJz/DW/GAJRCBaZyMT@jykWHmHAFDJcV8jb7/owJeM@GkAK6dzst2f@En/fDqcPJdlQC45VLyCe2vQnMuQn8jhi86P8Gssh66N8VXOyc8j9Rm44IJe7H7D9tMSh3FYpz4Hma6@p00PZeWkmiiGurTwTJ1qwrSk8a/FF0bZKDOSuS8wFf12sC91HIIxhQodvjwBkR0IffuUZ1iIDXCeIaE7@UZPL7TLz8QojsEeoQukcZlF5J4jHTzQmhmHIuFLA512IEqEsz8SMZvu48UKh4sxh04@RDJorLxPbkwQidiLVNMI2fnqJkidBtmVop62KVFfFfW96ZcphgWO@RaXLGEWIkDlXbCarDOgYFDjH@O7lCE/RLGeFfG7U/KrMuTnlbg1Ryt3wIIr/f00kwjMOFc4u4RxKJPSYPgFE0tSR5NVJVnDH@GqCM5lTCNYM1DEul2T/pdvLghQV7a@gWWlP6dqE@kjH8hO9@X0BZ@47aqnPj6JfeZTYAqIgxT8YFZMg5BknDfhR5qvrY3o@wc)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Boolfuck (130) [local](http://samuelhughes.com/boof/)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- YABALL (132) [local](http://web.archive.org/web/20060915202728/http://www.harderweb.de/jix/langs/yaball/yaball.rb)

### Explanation

YABALL is language that in someways behaves like a 2D language and in others like a 1D language. It has 2 modes: normal mode, and reverse mode. Normal mode is where most of YABALL's commands are. Reverse mode has only commands for flow control. When in normal mode the IP travels along lines left to right continuing onto the next line if it reaches the end of a line. In reverse mode the IP travels right to left and goes upwards when it reaches the end of a line. The top line is connected to the bottom line as far as the line wrapping behaviour is concerned.

The commands in normal mode are the same as brainfuck with the exception of `[` & `]` and the additional commands `?`, `@`, `^` & `v`. `^` & `v` unconditionally shift the IP up or down a row respectively. `[` sends the IP down one row if the current cell is non-zero. `]` moves up a row and switches to reverse mode. `?` switches to reverse mode. `@` ends the program.

The commands in reverse mode are `!`, `6` & `9`. `!` switches to normal mode. `6` goes down 1 row. `9` goes up one row.

The YABALL in the polyglot enters reverse mode very early with a `?`. It is then sent to the second line with the `6` in `#16`. Being in reverse mode we then wrap to the end of the first line. Before we hit a `9` that was added just before `'CO"14"` (actually 2 `9`s were added because of *99*) that sends us to the end of the polyglot.We keep heading through the end of the polyglot in reverse mode hitting a few `9`s on the way until we reach the Archway line.

At the end of the Archway is where the main YABALL code is. The `!` switches us to normal mode. The line of `+` increments a cell till it has value 49 before  we print with `.`, minor adjustments are made with `-` & `+` to print the `3` and `2`. the program then ends at the `@`

```
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.@
```

Because of the extra `+` now at the end of the Archway i redirect it with `\` off the bottom of the polyglot. `_` has also been added to catch the `.` for DOBELA.

```
+++.---.\_
```

#### Symbolic brainfuck

When I added Symbolic brainfuck to the driver I discovered it was using its current cell value as exit code so I added a `→` to move to an empty cell.

Answer (score 7):

## 146. [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/), 6292 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\D v'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(  >77*,68*,@'1   #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz( coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOxx4O6O@ 0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-0s

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #s""o
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1 "
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/

#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"--}

#1""/*/

#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _     @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002021 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6419 bytes)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKlhj4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZkvayn5cfxoShSokSRNEk99/FFD2bQSXeCmUyn07jpTvre28lgGph8aGRmgAQJMMDka5Afcb42BnP/wZ1VReply977dIe2yGLVqlWrVq1ataq4WOxxxvD3vz/CB6qp8nIgqyYyBcNEfV2aCbofpZboMycZ4UCQojBUUh9MJ4JiGqfUEWIRkhRe6sM9MtWxoEgrQYf4AEKarg50boLMIWciweA5TTCQOjW1qYlU8XC2IELZiTqSfDjnRFIGAGYKuqYLJkkPIdRSZG7S63MvUsIvCtR0SDdQRpB/nPxoIl6dTDilbwBkBKFMNZUtJV9giCJUVnVDwHh4wTBUHBlDaJEV@BegcQDldEktJSuXL5JYBl0C6ZwmCwvE9QxT53hTUhWcxKJGpdWo7eUgLK3pan/K4@qaQwGSMYtESRYMioeqXCDNbhg/DqAjpAtc3wKjRFVHOAuajGUkIV7TUE/mhn4eyRLA5pgYEjBH0QrS5aGBFtoEMBjqRNilw0CKIPSRoQm8JEo8KR0JC1NQDCDe8COJH6O5JMuoL8iQYUsS7wVkaGrsRFkE@Km@SiE4eO1FBTZ3xwLAKMKaCYIGTMVMUHEbAEfWvJjrnKYBkcDEBhBuShMQJcl0GkjgDAkLK2QxBKVP@KdtxFhFnLJbSzSTOMQBvVOd4DYEHbeNn@BFQ0EXACW3ESTXXJdMYAFmbxLVBE5HTV0Q3PsivVckFKbiEkxcET9pvvNzZ7aac0IzWjn8nGZSR3qweV2kOORPoOPHM/glHI4zKlvJoC/H9zhsSTA0taa7ODdK/BIZ9P29AL8F26MH@jMFWCngioxoVTNpzqcBgT4TCKQ5HMQh3yzg1@SdgtH5i7bYES4Lqg@tgQoKantJzfipruNeumUqN4ZKy6oyAH5CZfWpgvmhoAgDTcCr0Mm8SJgB11TFaiN1TjjcHErQaAZukp1@YekawlDQNiB7NkfX5RqqPCVwkNMwsQACVyArxlgQURuJnCTjLJCOUVlU64IxlU2cZ6r0ccuDLhH6frQmg1f7GGiizqA4DpCSCOhLk50eSIgCYGgIlVQVJ/30T/@iPxgAniTPq3rfFtc26qs80YocIRZUDcICqyqcTMgCOC8u3coOBcw4WepzJi5eWdpFECJIqXN1KveRCgXqcwm61pCbQXcURYE3BUvILUXqRRNubOkNyZJcqPiE60HDkgJI2aTaPvQ5Da3EC9QRkRnfZGqKMeTTsshp0N@7Pp26Pn28F4A4t999ckzTgzMQOP8JiYI753uS007uKTrD5AxV6lPa0hyqSgD5eOTgE6omKC7nHg6n16n3nG4/1mcu95mU4P2ipPRdTpDxFJTrdJ/xCf5OOn04e5F7t0TAMsdYcG8VXLzbQYHGIX1iRk84SfFrS9T22aGdNNV4xBzHyf6daMyXl3EzK@KIjCNYLFUsH6CG/IYsCJqL8bNurCUw3MFq44RDFX2Bw67wqfTgcR45PbtVJxigpnsVxX21KalYa8nacAo6GpiiGBpobx2LLs@B8BhYiZswmHtRj4g10fygWIhKnAtOXUA90KNrMSI90upxOL8P60kbw7YHreH2O7TQ3@nPoAugS5vGK6Usq3MomNCGhy/QIAounBtAE0Fmq0JJq0JWiSRmv2pjBfQKxtYTUMzXk6Av4F4Hqt0W/Z06AngwYMEANquv7KigCbcELLw1JG77DZJE6FIT0BL6EvECVj2ggwRrXMGFTEk3NMCMwQYN4wuEw/td7VVPM3U66bsFXb2i3@1QuPK7fQrrGyQKcyRzymDKDbAlpUAWjucFzbT1FdTEMEEjvRx2SKTPHkP9xpA6/vyybDKW2KPrThlY11utZ4@IHFYyti3lk0GnIs62BlFf0kE7ycuXpQPA7EXhjh8wyB4BPzjeIGFtCICQCQuBn5qg3ECQ50OJH4LsYuoUSz1aY9HL4iFqt3RQ8D5xUzQmhr34LkD56U0UJuNNFD7coq/xwBiLUV3sRZDG3414HzNnTA4gVjckwniwE@unOT/I3ldwTlRFPYAUGLlBi0H2U6x2AIOsgY1BGL/W1hfprBsLcdNE0GagPaDng/wNTVMzTmG4kMzhtOcHSaGb@rJgVhUsLLSpLyVTtcI9We2Bejagf9LrEmh@2pMWLypE4jZtODKoGdhhooESMIA/TUHqXE7RAMVJ4tMYeCfJQRQ4QWGdHQBIgPzAKJdoEJWcA6XSWCq8y@EnXckPnc7hRQ7ccR1uCOBcG76k1QnWQqhD7ANs8KV00FwiaCtb9xPVzx0c8TZjADHvnE7/SJUU1xfnx48fnafOC9DwHz9@gtA5Dn3CIQ@EPpGQj4QwnB@HSA4vCeHUO5IDxz04n@/WmBfuB9xsCzw6rSTNxd2dngYfvNwda18D@OoGVQeaDaB9@AJ4nO5EAgfdbsfFHCrq74lW7esWZ/tEGuqCMqCEhabqJqpUM9nHWrKZTzjoqaHTstSjFRhfHyfQg2Eu4ziQHyYl6@wQrKuqmSANhuMJdA6A7DkcZapT6PMw/5Amklkgsx9ZwYK9bbR1ahrK3SKoSYJJ2aPRVtbxRGjbNlAPAl/YnROJujrZaDiDEvihihzHQQe25femqXjYt1NDOHVqT1J34qM4foInmH6eGvA88qnW7SbSBoxhQDzp9MNkjhp4PBiSTEI3kTZknKDEE1G/3ltHfmGZZxy/mYXujCO7GA@lv51pg5wlyA1lami4coRnB6bTNnwEA/fVniAvIiGfIIt@c7HyY3URCVHWBfn6b0EcyEstVocyUCb0fd9CfJHA6ZRFYRPGsBJMWVBJMsjqw24zU5sOck85rA4c3B@dHNuUwNaUPGz/OnaxEGEGARmrWF1uQ49g7IX3UMD0/XVOUTKG5LQH@oqi1ykktzHpieR0AODUtqmgS@AJPmZJEU8PsVmnqkgR5gSMjA4EGbBKUji6Ti54nDhEz/6It0dMTxCnMGWke5KCw18B88VjBFLs9aS3QIEvmPT19QCYPu0dYhsI1/CVUYT2GG9OdVMW@vb1v/xBHxrgdfMMuSVMdfjxJvAIfMNN5RPfbC07K74hp8MtS2BGU1niCBtI6GsoeQ5PRzl5EziMGqtk5PMNOR0ad7luXBBOfILh9R05syjXBXnaF9bXw4UQFu@bXlZuRZqQGsEV25FkHH0j@wvD0cqPp/O6rHJ9gsVaZpGEbWtb7SIsuAFUjt7RSKAhv4HOtX2HtusqYMiYU@uMl1K@1q6Shn@HuXK6L2RMmOuxAkxDuZ70Bh8xGZG3JNvqMNj08IkyN7aCjzh4uLJWdXRpMACTy76@BQb2NUyBNI4X6Dm5vCMW68EAkYGeew@nLlvnt0DWi8KbwFuAUFWZnH6O8BFx4KGHYNnBC5q@HTZJLxgrc70lNtGGP1@KcIFklAUlk@A9HiaIB9zNDHi7dKppb@fHFgLJH48fzm2tshIEvCqKgvC1ngujjzThZF@gvxN8UxGvTdpt6ADoiJtxYOzKnAFCYtpsFmbQLOT0nuDiAYXH4rINvSO2W3LWCx1vzZW3eTSJV2XJ0Ehzr2/e0ogvZxlbNHgdnZy2WfHda/72wbDHg7VvEzrcqVXexPPVN@ToG5SUNVXEk/EdwfCrb/GOV@f496aZMFRngnU@PHCtDlL1DSrIJxPJgMni6@x9/mviihc@yekwF8cHqTJ5@WD8KSqrqj4UFAMF/Aw2cxSyWg/Dtixbc9dmofq2TBuSrBqoQc7v8QImBIZhnQ9L8y7bJE7x8UOrj23Ch7MdJIoMcihJzm80LicPVDkSG9AcnN6UgKkuYk1vX79Vw200FMt@VUNtjB5VYe3rm6p9DP9fEw6yDqvj5Ymd4Du21CF1Zk9r364gzAvwmuPhyuWYGMnpp61Z3FsNoPPDObdcX/8Oo8db3F2PHtqSmMxg0@EM8RgETN0yo/8upYXeL63/bTrqFdro1yqx07hjWQCNTc6vmhQFGPZn5mAZ5ts1lihPhalwUINUeyMBxOY93fHtRDF2NY7tdQ8amIcf0W6gVvaE8JuoxuM5vntX4XCyBJ38q9bMQVWjgZ2t4Ql0DQI1HHidcaBMtb3G3eFdfarU3@fcUFv3bLW/RyRO@bkaKfZ1m2nPFDcE8nvLbM9OVJj2qhOwIZRvaH8bKVkiss57iEnMFvNIwqtV@rt4T9FmHRPsV7BHoFWlseHDS17fpngCb83XCXA8DjMyRTCX@PwWtw8p0p6qyj@ndUCf9iVspoHxiX0VvtZKr2wfe0kbbVcmDLzK0RPfWpOwxhp78gjcwxPlNxu6BlUyyeDwLa38ag3wnVFrZ0Xwa3NIGLHJwo@h8@vwW/TWcedm/TF/9F2C16ti9DrwHrK4P/gt9pG2NnrJgitepLWWZbfOFkcv9I@2BE5JfZ/BD4WJQG7fsfi5/mhqrC9vAi1U/DuQ7KfJkukb@TQJOryCz3tLwDsmkakqgkGbnD4Q8FxFFjiwRq3Yt5TseiX2IHMLE24g5L4qWdtlB/ywk9elveDhBYhT6/kDD9m@okasaaCqjIWlsb4eNpaXPLTndPIutkOdnMerm1/t1X764OrzV2w@ZagOlaEw1EnP2Ny91TdAIk3LDeu9SgD9Q84Y46e7RCFt53hDY5e7sirL38JdrBAt9aiqhxdes9irqg9ZfxbeJdeDBPvy1TU6GLcJk8gA/lbfGQpTGJ4M1VQ1wUfu3gKV8QqPdT68llyoOg3UkQS9j2uCZXECRUs9WUBzCUgYGbtPBw6vHvVklcMOBO9Y8MCZ9fVb1qN4VT9syV1yqgnG6fsjbo7Q87VxOSWZ@GH/4CuAe83TEzhTkca03b/t28NyvK9tSdUk5MvgaL8sATP0pR@3cmI3vYEvhcM9WyrZ7pPvVis91fXlezD2wzzi/LXxDzC8ttcaxEm67aNkbBwBjwoKrwvEW2D99BgdYR@G6WQqc6aq@xGBc7k4j8ftpqxMeAVhoADYGoq4YmH/DMvLy0CyZJgEVhLR3R06/rI4ZU7ZZ5RAjlMHeniwsBJPgexCIz5UdSvr3TH3kDh2@nzOY@e9cooYJwEVZJjQHQTl9uBEiVwsOrdVRwo3IS4hOLyu6Znld2IMiWsXiEwfhLgFFglZfVJ1y3vCctFp4scO//mv@7bHGwxBBppIBhjwAwV7aaoTYajOP1nl2qUnNY3DHnMYx3yI19Vx6b50EhnQBWHIJY5u6hy1cs2Y7Tdj@5HCTQ0PPDtUWI2KjSHszWVajWZR01cFSyzsgje51pXiVXk6UaDj982h4UcNUAcC8cvZPEmFEAZTTB1rv74XFVBfwAu@fUwYGfBlVR2TR8SYkv/815a3ECRKWIRweF08cRbcKRFhI4a46PC8OgWq10hWgq7aIC7MZBh0ptiWBqEWrHg34occcWMCSfStnXhwMZYjTzrZQL4scmJnV@wacCaJruNk/bJ9xzwkfokmtPBf/oB2f7H55viFLxoxHF60Bjl7xnK1mxyG5G2qEzmOFw67WtitkngRboTKdp124TBprrVTzoR4ZBK5E@bEKYc861bwmIpdHRUD@gfcuglqq9Mkjl1Ty3DzNUwUxh7BYAtxELJ8OIlzG3YwwVmOF@hHNMSy4uMRG2bgzmKIjH2aJonU@qFdcPe5Kp0RelPyjGEW8AeCCVKd48fE@QUJ6UJfxS6Gd9/fLwKM734RzT7Qxpo59/eLXzCBG@CeCmPK8Xc07kDZSubLsf@C@fFHg1sih@PZeWY9Z4ZefvylVqhlG81ks9UAbj5blT3KqfqE22oKLAuazPHQfWTiuwls0SXB@Lr22GiQzR2Au1zomEPn2Onb7d4kbEBtVjt8jmMruAEB42o391eyH8pvCDvprwFszSRKyNaiqEYEyZYZp7GrQb1r2cLtgrv7FHT2miP4qf8BVUh45EAJ4JIPuPSNPEKva2m14CcSAc34dUa9j@MQCuDVFuI1AGbSpixcXyvdqtzByj//N6ixBuPa37fGBMe7NcYQ79UYALfZSI5cslBq1bP7mUCcto76YMDq@PULkfQty@XXki7Vdi9dayZi@xm2G9lGtxpoJhnENsTyJuKRAaZXpDuSR40G1i4IKzI/SsoGaPJ@H1RTb2lizQYq3U/cSywfE5@CHEfALP9moPUiB4VhjcRrN0PQXHMetNgPVuZjAkcwG9QBt@h7gf7pn/6F5Qp9b0L4j@ywCOF/YoW/pzGDXrtzWjRuWIPZ0i7UkEGMUlzxCbfYqRMesfCIKClTAUkT4OCMMASDW8Ru67vF47prAz@hEYCZWPVibUvKE/QHF3bGO6VpbGDgZQQ/cVEQFjwxV4lv3tMUu6bDAEFHwpEQSwORvtkaoU@yEPo0C6HbfQqyRs0kLfFDj0fn5@fIYfCcLCQiZxYj6WPu@6Djhw2hxwBLWbbIHYI8kGWbA9Iu7GyuY87DunFW3OWcrBM9nIGZYbULjFQuEgAQN45WbH44YChUbVZBoyvCwiTqfLm2scDAUYiPlWC9oLBG5ANEFm7sQf1SdrdPvrFH0I40@3ebwdHBYA0Mduo4JDp336N78155sB3pEQjMbw4IkgLhPz7gXb@RnuRrv27XS69sXBv0uaGo2BsiB9QiV4AOBGk24t7pKQ4bFdCL@8WPgBJ6AvQsXpBGqmYk09lCsVprvPJLJpDOl2BO5Lw499z7/N67h03A@ULq10xN5ehGOZVbs3KXqu2CIobYriq@JPNQaS8pfaP0juVy8LpskvCqIJb5VsRkBu/LkYX319i3qfQOYNp6JPqqVJf7y/Pdw/nFvXL0qvgfD72yceQ/wcIFoXuDvLDhRAd0TmHtSNHEr9kZ/rVnXsCxfSFp449o3W@j3/Ys3ry0t3UvXrtsYNfiwAXdF2a0MpVlyv@GMwfU3U9bRRHfWouwNb2ga9akspjUbYE89WpReJcaZNfl9fuFtovlhklVa3pKXp3gFJiZ6BJvQRtEQVuTWOLnD9OYgrmd@cBsCi/kkQnekkxmQFVsHjD3JbKcBTNzuwablIYwkXzNNT1YcWzdhUGRYTfYIdQN5vVnXOJugTaOie95EvsNTZZMF3bhXfjxJBFq43LjCrDnsoA9gM/jD7a7MVp7BXuIY3FtCvyqqRraTswzwjpUh7kZykwBOYiBgIrTCcCJ5FIX8CghoIrqg8zAR@eaiDsoxWXXwT/ph6F0/1BY9KUBjDQutxdU0i9YduuSzLk9MKF2gh62WHWJn5zvMuZnuVHvcIy74/yS0hcWLvzKzOkD5g7EO@edmdPteCUDxJfbduzuv3TqXisLzrR77dYh@oVCiMc3imC/78Tj/qFBYcdRmFdAiQ1TL0EQxlCXOOE05JoSr3gD@RG5dd27FK9h6m7ku8Dj2RwpyOMhMxK4kAQ/IjlFEpJkvFTlwu@SuegEtDOONZQ@vqwkDd2xfv8DhEkhbnSM1xTSYG7g2bibAoMTspwStDAAw98ppmgOcy9MkXU9JsVSeEFAB6iDyaQjD4akAwIvSK3RxXdoqw22PdDiajx@arfGvjqMIxCL8wMaA9AeUHNrixP4a3v/AdewEgOoNEw1JVAon68ERYH@6gKZmUDvRNwUhEx3e9fvN3u378iREo4sEvO2OyEQuv/uXNb5RVbBnjmmz8i89uwZxv0f7vHAL9pD/5L@B7SfPvviOpYTSxqMMfeF63iYYD3BE4/nWDlxHSvYHPnuOzwdfj4Ga@fR7/A7FgDkO5bdZyDPYB0ljpWzY@7cddxPBE5IDrj1eNxfIMMvDdr/5Zh7po@/A2vCCzG61Ttdx4YbdwfG72efgT7cQ45pL8jMF5cDOcjbybj4Y8njwTT4jx8xAb@k7xseMq7cN2gy8z6zjVx6MFmrkX1bZdMSr962thhoR59uNHqYuIVbT4we18C7r84dSDtkH/3@90dsBCZRnyJBl/opEPx4coSOPjvoE4fu@HKfQTPnHScG/E8PtXGtduO@d4FIOo/SVQcbcnyP0AlNHdEnzI9Rmv7hhx/A@kR3F/4L/4P7zud8uHMhdBGNnngjsRPvZydLJtEwIWNZtysQcNPovoHuoxx34gkFPitnWXz81//zv/7qv/4p@fsV@f1HJEmSZvT78FOHaIxWcIxFhP9JeNXfCXM43BNXLvwmKJhyCSxmH@Bga05nOOhsfI9fBPn0Ef7IPxybW3z@SGLsaALy@vjoRq6nBXV0wR@tjliWPVqSv0ccZtnFoeNxJ0yzbOBe@YBf1Y98/PwBWCZ4yHF6@pnMg5AjGnOoKrlBQ8AaRuoRjJwLAfUQWvjwQR0tmhz@Q80e/qub@K89xn91Hv@lxvivtMJ/h0iijn6ZSHh@7uH3P65D1NEP5z8k/h4HqR/QAXOao4uLh@dnj@/O//2Z5@wM//A/6IN18IwcVgiIePD4POd35@f@i4vFhe/h4o46@gI8eaaOAg4Q3vsT6iixOK8TSu8yFzbNT/Y0vQThc9/DXa0EpnjTGzj3HQVyybQ30Giljli4C29vcWIQ39azyUy1BdC1UjbZyF4W2tlWDeKNh8eLz589fmiVz8CdiwegZfELz4UnYZomun088aN3j8cDIeuWOspcLFq07xzILdkxdVKQ7x7u7t3@i4cfqaO7ozvXp8CnACMzM4Yds@OyWt3@V6uLRagaqX5GkC4tmJGqM0NmyPZBVhEjtJgls1wwE7XK9iEowB8zgaDEiAtmwCiMwrJ7@N7@n1TVclUFVCpkMxeMibEyIlwH1WoZkIlQ8Aj@JIZhFkDogpnBPyOTfsN@/8jgOrqZ@3vqDjl@EECh@Fmnn3H6I06n9BCOaE9fngORpztiboTjD3fCQjIfHMjrfLy/i8fjzoezI9q4v6ctHesIhBxnGOT5@fExk2wmHx9pvPqyOD/2fPb4PsORuPCc25dPR/2Ls0/3pz4s4ZaU@x@P6PNP9xdBHw5HPMD3AMSd0z@712xQwvXjPeV0zTudDv515rO5FSIBK@6@s0nFpw4NUVYIR8GBQelD@fcDi9fC5nLdhR@@PLvd7g/3zjOnxSiXCwlgo7sc7P0iIKKAw02M9ziMfGwQ21eRsPviIhKG@0jM7XMxJNnKcu/QNO3e4SeLAX7i8pRIJHWdWxKgEAy@9w5Of7x33AUeEol4mESHffEIUnVfPOh2uN3fs@fndhkBN0Q7nAuHqjvRl@fdP9eX53MXOdz4z@3Gkfb5wu2CZHcY7hZfXItz17kLx0EUzvXl@QIHCdwXCN253A/u52crDs4u97mF88INfMMrHv8N/1UDGRpyHj0fYaNJQaGw29VbCu5QxBXzxO2/xEeogMsRdAahXg4n57y7@3wSPImG7j49nDycuM5P/Cf3Fw97CtztPELQVdainWCPMN@oI/9Z3cEGHE4s6mf40YUqC35ZHaBg/GxfGJyPrpOXR4yNe048n@9O4nGr7JOTHz9CrwR0UJgDjiOQX@RC5xfnG6HaYFy4LwD2C7KZDOHnLyBnViLYYC774cT9/YKxejs66yWOvxxxz2cEP3p2OM/25JXgdznPyNMrxxfHMaffsQ@OZ8fxl94zNlZPWDexicKhs7OTkBWOxiDMnritBdkwA3frMKQIBscTxXB2hMXJCTx3Q60SPWEgKWCg7jHJEw6H6QCcF7@IZAML6gw/5bEeKTl8DqsDoVic4DtChhGnYD7Ug5afoygDo7aMX@dQRfGjFQ8TO9QTBLCtBVnGy5N43gPmv9yfw1z7I3UEegxMLEOAY1LjhKkgzKfTubA50pJxyo2QawTzdnz89Js//Ok3/@NPv/2Tn377hz/99le/@/Wv/hB@fw2/P7Guf/Jv42F8/t2v/5f/9ae//C1E/kf4/Qf4/fvf/fpf/IH1I/f/CX7/907cf7J/O3DWjwJc//h3v/7Tv/rdr//Jn8PvX9m/P3/5@@nP/p31///Yfzj425/@7D/hk33zh39C/e3f/Ab//@nf/O1/@A3@/9/@9d/@zT//23/8b0jgL6zA//uv/q11hsJ/9cc//Yt/BHX6Mxz@hxCGf@TxWYfHBvgjHPnjMQPmJrr/cRfyR5qFEQjRO5F/hH68xw6l7BYS8P/LH2kGBknGgtzg3IX849/9@p/9FcT@COMry9qQ/2id3ZahPcgNndiMs8r6IwD@yx2YP/rpN3/w01/9Dz/95i9@@s0/psBuhv@P6CMVQPiKTziSBEhocUKFgyCq6zC7DQdDJByG8yHjAz/O@fR5L8rCfXIImAB@IukfD9oyuIyTNW2HCvu4zn8Qwyf0GZJh2CIj1wKf8Q3E4DDReuSyjlrYgOTegrHvd3JaMdY92sm@H48jdzKuL4eirQRS5BoI2cgWdqFoi96uBrWmzAJevIqgkF09ioqiVg1O9cJlvrlzbWaT6TwVQalqJfPiEraBwqiUzTU3t1ErdZ01vEHRzZZKL2/tS1edIp7D@onsGLEgezr5z89ZlqIuvvjOz6mLRrYJ8c0qYgOMn7q4QQs/qtWufc/UBV6eSVg6kQ1FvvgYg6KwwvyIwlGv1@/3wwlfveQgV//x92sQ9m1T@chwOFSqjJ9ExFnLMUTCuSCkC3H8KBx07Vwhngg9vK3IVHs7Ei44Cgd1aTA0kTlXNwCGYYCJtTG@1obXxgDroB7H4d/PPaAEYfcw348wrTJI3KsU@TU4lYchZ4Lf78f@YyaemUsiYig/boxAIB4Lx@LBQMwbi8dCYTYSDnvZgJeNxqJxxgtz8hgbiYXjrDcWigdDoVDcC60bjkepI0HpSyJNw4yKdTgQCUgKj19cPcdvAKv@4QV11BdESRE@oIWr7/5w1F9HoGkMOYKxewY5aNrBRij8BPNkkQDTHD/bDbKg2RyUg0M8Osrl0kwu53Ck8A3oZybNOBx9fBOOMUw05XAIJCUdCzIByDTEd9kIg18DcEj4Jp3M5TCGEb4JxDAOh2NspVg38vomCmAKvgkGMQLkcDxt0DGAXLUoipFcpnXDMKm0wzG1yIvBH8AlrbsQITaLb3ACzpSzUtKQ5nBcrjPBsONw1C04u6j8ur7JpMNRsG6SSYyiSCoftip1hW@S5IBMOtyB@DocAwgMdDAoHI4eBLEQOxw8hPglB3ETCGG3WcXkHI6lVQ9cE4djQaA5fuxwPK7joRygJ5/nhmZfGFjHUreuPCQVIElaTLO53uVlbzDo6ctk9rJOkorFPDdaTvXeoGdn7D3CoeJckDSeLF8eAk56fOTkw0lXkKS8SHpcPgqEwkfuCSizjwEuaPJYxElFSDq02mEjhGMCwD18pCZwTXE9K2l9kCRyXfR6jjOQWgr3H7R0ub@QeacLGdJKALXjYrxTmA2FP01jjkjUcXoCV8cnRxCCCxdinGDfOpz3Dof7Lv7wyRENO06dnz75nN@xn5AjGnecOqJRB3KfOQLQ@cIORwQFog7HLZiEwsDnRJ8cZ7pgTnUFBc6eMQWrBHNGKEFPLnzlvPjcc3@xwXpnz1j5AplPrpUnwXrRyv0JUwzTOpgIu09JHc6eafocVAPpzDQO2CqbrKcDZMzhAz2@TbZ0yEYJIJ8PlDiCHxgvGEBLWOxwOeIuhE1XBOd7B7HsrZVOl9MZDTidbucZIPmIHDtK3X1GSEYWa11r/jiAI8CfOExEbSa44j6YJiFfHCrwiiR9fGqYnI6XvkmJp8gRiTtwNN7OML4u7LPXx3pPT3rh84v/jrKGqAhLHT1TffxOayiOzuJneBUJ5pPnF3aeK7SMDjz5HZLPqGMnJtoZ3JtdH5HzMTb1jnxBNaQeHR8fU0fnzQtH0FH1P27WDC5osvZ0f3EWSqTxcgBYgf77x/OPP38pDmf2X3xeL6Bd4KXDV0coROkCdtLq4x0Rrel@LIz5OkDGEaA58/xdDiiZSgBS6gzPCB1HGvQxXkZLvHSJ7q2Knv/yiKwHoNqXtdPMVCHP9U7L@CmOizttkN0H7h6Q@5cVSf4SC/ouyDI4FlQELf3ciH8f/T72fblVbVVzn5nT2Gns/t5uTi/rZJ2kqayFs88wYEn1LHVk/OhWw@wvleLZ0anmDIacYBvfJ46syrNR99FFIOo3uOXRg@1x6gpFscDCPZkjBlh0JHb2j/nezWxClhShqNg/6A8GUuAflH/48ZimnU6w1Y8vvnzD8Xx3fv58jo9nO4BPz8/P56/@yWV7vAGzTff8ndan/I9HD5Ff@s6t/3M4pasWdxyRsMONnYiN7x@/fzxCMElFjkAY92QPjaxp6O6k2bU4Ub4/UeBPODHInyCQW@Xk/AKiDIiw7wUMIbhPaJq@DoCREo9HYpEj6vc0/d4DeEjdPJESBUE3ppNDj6SSulTm8OM6ZfNYCgLl6UrQ4breYnFtzSBszuBnrtie2Y2zTZydKLIz6X7c0qCx2x@OBYsX72FJdrxFIlaPLrwMYxL3LXSC94XF3s1u6gv1AXBNeZN4DMLpjKI@YNc1fOtaw3nRd4bpxm49jJv68MFW94bpN8xHjBxnsiN97BkFyhvYw/X7BsJPC4mXjuUSzWFHMFWzXh2Tl8jKZJDxzDLMiDczLneH4BMkWlRAbU4QKZFQjitnFf/BAutNRUxKrlDKQh6UQCJ56mzndug9vAMYqd5H0W0XjhiIwlgwOOEUAceAgA4iXQS3e4L9rnkXgfQgFqeL5Ok1QIGh6iWUeJFoZ7zDtw@QHaMXeVk1ALFVusuqATp5tIu167AeRXElgIW4dmRsIkOtPuC9duvhLVXuHtzoy9q704VT0TkKbN1PbVzQGNbmvSQjP@lbgkO2VrPZTLCxD15o2jPLS9C1gbNjtox6pk5M7@TMairtjLpy8e4v@Onm2S8n333Hf6/dTR7O3JOEia8ezwSGyrFLskBOzMQkAeKh3UkPZ@adxyM9JCbuKxe@h1EYbItnSrSYbbjtukHNlQTQgj0gDLd3daf4fqk8eHN3igdInnpPbhMrL5dgvAv4SWBxyN6nBGvXA8o0EyuPcsadww8/aN3zwASzwcOd7UXhLGOXnFjdcQ8J4IcMGT2eHFQG6DTuZI/nwQ2Fy5D4OuOZ/N13nEe@WJzJPp8bQ30f/JS7MyHw4Eng@1MXd774tLqbQv5TF1wTUIzsBuIhn83r5w3tQN8Z8Nhq0y3pFo0LTN4CyJskEie3n05uTxIfP67uFr7Jg9di/ymzlQZM/AITf7bj4eo6uXWjFywhS6Muxy@k01/4Twzk8EoeDzDZq@3ktCg8uYUUDcZum@pnrC/JnqLrh/hYwmyvTGsLNrJZE1l7J1ufGmS7Z7OP/dMhb9LgJckGt14s0CSYHHN4k1IvUlTFxxEInGbvcYwT7xefPlHrom2XQSgZK5eegDg8ySZbXOp4nZbsl229r/M1/XpIDa917mZq2SjcZhFMY4ORne5KVBPpcIbO32EQrAa@MM9nlsayHEVB2RDtATBEe2A4H9YimEm2nrAhE3YitNa6gSAX1hOi9b4S3uvLwPoJ1Nu254MKsciAznyADMk7ShDdBPIkQQhJ56Q8CEBXoT5AJTANuA7SA7oARYa@@w7Zt@cJmJpH8ViAwTDcyMNioFeUQuHfQCngwFSOQEaxPiSFAG0fcAp2b94rKPT3K8h@O8EFGTwjr/WSgp@8pOCaKob1bg7mm9siA7fFhw8jTyJkEwT/ZKoA@SHt@fdH9nB/itLVcq3VzNbLyQacYcoT226jfLrZcPfVNpsa3j6zJynEmZfn6qzQLfJgwoDhauLdmPB22n1UbJVQIFDJePHeCcD6I2t5DAbU0w0mwSD70hl@VR/Qc2ks0fv78OOtj4nfMNn137feBxmTQwZnefvG0PaFIQMvcMFgbr/wvbcT@0QwDHv3UN96Q3ay6Tx5d2qCXwGCXmjvNkpcstZeJcSHCT@i8BLPOF0aSGSX7aGFYC8/2RjStLKT/kHhXUL7nMlhiabiMYY5RYwXB9h1ILAOBNeB0DoQXgci60B0HYitA3E7wK4xsxZmmJ0Gg5FtMLoNxrbB@CYYYrbBLYZQYBsMboOhbTC8DW5LC21Ki8QIXnS05ibpuoKO09hQbJ2G3/hTTBIZBjTsy8gQEBp4BQnZQ68iobzYfmQ0ztgFFegqBgoEItt70D5r2ITLospr0eG1Srbu7EgYqyhrokYENqvroJWyC7wtMgid@xThNyAoCtQu4mWBA2NAMMFKSeRA/gX3qfVmoL483b4FgTEk2M09ZMfbhkIeluzwbYnPgeTAoWQLW@AgNuvVSrRhzM4rJDaRFpWneyOthTG0F7eL9SNWsJijb0AELAjcBvvvnKzLbOrTg0UG3y9yD@HBIl8RZeENH8qFeeMiyBPrrGT8J9gS6/IsO0UgrQ1mgP05ByIDLxoUvyKa@MKeOn736z//39Hvfv2nv0U//eVv/79//z/j8L/Dp/8DbBYU2AD8yZ/i07/Ep3@OT3@JT3@2k4nAB08dP/35b@D2f/o36Kc//FMr6Z/9lcMb2iCCFBy1zfmrf4hP/wif/i@HN7wB/NUfW4A4i8P7TO2ZVi6A@pP/iBCUhrFskP35XyPk8ICB4bIl787q4w87L5RZCDZsuCOhh5fp1pkf6pjtjNvjALz2Hbu98@AGcO8g1zn8fYJt3wNzxnJkxlqa5/ghfmnIjlINbP/w2IRRDf8A5G3eB6PHXttwQu3/e3SKnB4MA9HkzdiEpcPt@tv1dmxTMazHQQN1eMtfGxUOuzeUwPSWAvkmM4Gl4cfTFjIjZS0Zsflbwd8/WQ8gjrVkSaaLdVN2WevcMOlB9jby8L@d6mKhxcOQ9WYp@ZwDZb//wu4UuKduXjQblPIyBqaM23fNdrOSCGGiQZNAtg2/MWPxDeGC9yW6bcvZ3SZbzb3oMPjogYk53tVIm4ISyOH4CizmtA3vxhZXcB/eotcGuGNOgw97b64dAnbc3Nw4qJ04BsuQ3ncRDDuVslTGJondTwrsJAV2koBmCyfRNeFA4AUNZODAenH/LU0r246K2s@2FS7cc9btgMmAuaC1pukV5akxTLxGTTTyvrJ7jXwHJfuQsPvJvUJ0zgVyuF9lAJz7eRIv2/IwauYVzOuGOpwTc3svZq@13sa0l2enUxDuUS@5tGk5Nn6o5fYLfAc1@@D5xoICzN@zIN83FhQJf72gl82K8@6hf5u/X1c7azWx0fBbZFbHP9oboPDQ@Ocgelt1hCnWSdDlhilP0p7y9OYqch34XgDE0@vNkvY@EqDvbKGEJzEV1RSs5YHPmgpTDhVbwTsfGTr0oTD7mz4DRdUFY/eNVMl6u0dx4neieXWgwKjmxZs2SfYXMPAjd2v3i/1xZTOy2VZo2vpuEUZtMQpbno@PkiKZj49gfMqie8tAfOvn8SsXTgp/8AhCO/ldG9O2qrlUvPmc6f46TmLvWtmaEj92VTU70QmFJBFM6HhBhskXGnL8GH@6i7AEV5G8H4ot0p7pcmMmDtWJOhAUFb8OjnO/QF/Y4sYEcZpGaPEizov4HYrsSbSL93JuO@vVz86KrgIuzr3JH9hHsMcML9Jf8hhzVj9Q3OObxVnZ1uU1fj69jV16G@/TK0q6Yb6kmUTi1R58/XlFB11bDAC4JSP4dTK89g4Qr8jZI2UTjb/DYWX4ZhL7gsHD8IcpTQJo0gb3iyAf3s2dAXcbwttv8f/9Blxnz35r8xFjtrEEfTPJYtuPTNEMsv@NwgsuAC@4se55XdxGtDPfWJY90SEzPC9yEMWl4Dd3oGNqmqAYm2fNa8RfkXnsC/RK7omDUMJKPECTPvOiceDtJso89gWZWwp9lw3p3cG7rnFd4PpEX31bxbGiI0pPtT6@4mK87J4pRt6wJECnb4gM55253W@LlQUibaSHPIwjFBbe5h9ZuHupmvEiaMJ6BqLqoEGPyNYqZEMbbaktrbeyZeubb7YetcYfqyUr@GX1rzIE@GB90Yv1bot1v6c@665Nlb5hRNjA@verjF@8XGPErz6@bsOfx6Kv15SsMmwyJdatvGedvNXi0nstviMVa5m0rJJvE8mvCd03y9yOqFnItios/fOGkFeY05ws87xrF6MV826LqcornYDjcIupyhujyuMBhbrJSTSdiTfPT1j2hZuSIFiA6wyubbhihDAHfbQEal03bNeul7xIyoTTdqwWO@aOx7boDhfdu88Rd6CodRgv5D5vyuTfLJN/VSa/V@amB@wXuQNE8XtF2q2Am@e9JpAF0XxDO@MkPHOHy3tqGw5F5XT87PWLU3KeSl7knDlPQSE7Bedp1gVK2dl3nmZIwHCeNkhg7Dy9gsC2bzl/dJ6uuwUG0OGWBD7jeFuF43veeZp2uZ8p8qXPdbl@5@mmTQHmk3VLOPJsLa/27Kf@6mZVVRC8llHpRVhiDLiouFp3D17yY@CfgNr7lUHixwQKnBBgPAHZGzR2RgyrHBg2/ORTgq5Dw8fpemnKXt/YrqFAuiexs6iCpWRK9JHzyLmvjCzCcCpZfIQrEIj15ulhihD7amb2NXLs0kFCSSPvl0@45yf2QN9F0u8AeHcRR97mX7fXPgqrAb@NTpz5LTpfkbMujlCEnQHcB8jCTP3B@U6lcFu/2PvKav3dFnq9RoAb0bcGsVqJoN3R6WDDYduUFKap2r6QkFT8tE/azYMPu1Ni6X2RjWgFu2e@kUyi7ZphxbDb@d3vVWcnHyZtTwXhxDvmweplm3GB6GKctNV1O5aq1fmAhB2d0yfbVghYbDN2kMBZ6sZLxoq3hqF1XqtIorn21SRk9uOX6qacaZW@fS6DX7X7edPXdU4wwYFGjGAn56YUS7@qP8N@Vy37fW1Qr5nwooBDhvXhofS1ef3uKPuCcnlb7OsGxIlelHEfNI42JWxZDrODHcv8PVl7ZeLjbypZRr5V6Ab7C2t/zbbNnOArfHs5t7BwYStBn@1HjvHC7DjwNqNeWyTyzL82Wvy4JBuPVfENpduqvU@rVfFDTYxT8BgNl5/dwPp@A@82HsZHKqC/YLnVy/G3Kclzik3fxmvqO08urKcOKvYS2@zkthMJ6p74r21ctCCi@ljPVCulLgy60WjU/fpRBO61kHc7jlPvPibYTFsCXrxtD/liNvadGKq6@fFecbx2KSMRYAxw5LmNJX52H3fbumxHn7/ou5DPgt3hqI1rvO0G3J5WwqYOh4dsyeartZ@364SzkazNW@C3l8zW8FMjLB34gc7jIxm@Hh@xc87joz2K4abZPEb6/ZH9Sa/Azmevj/a9mYjFZbzaGwMvAEwn1keX7QU4e9cLyw/lCH/g3Fzn3uSaKqa0dnbA60P4EdXGM8IVZN3Wd9HXMdbny0FSXYEQnsIGwvgdZSsXhsYLn8S10i7no2Xo4C1dDU1V7O@bjwWFmO14g1ljvfRKyJ4qc464gVilkFerdyiyHLLWz8XIJ4vJDurW96E5xVpCXvPGi4SBnzzxCcRhyjGWNGtXt43rh@EmmQjBxEcLeNyThQn@bDDI7oHV5LIErTLMSYMBCBJtb1JvObg08ZeEfaroS693KzlCbfLxZ3s3TNsnjOxEa68DAztde9vNGCgQAWsq7gXObn/AWOwmg/CWMgxx0iJQ8IvCJWoFY96dvB9dS/f@lV0fbozvo@sRt6z1Tqak4w3pZ5yyw2f7Vc2dpWn7oSXRAztPLtc7J1H2TlcJ8pzSj33UNJfjyLHeTwoHLbcJTubXG7G48BZAp9QHhSge7AGGeMu3BgxcBRtt5PGae@OSqqBfoGCAfGETyiNWKikWcFhP9vawQxpkxcRa3n22gnH8ou/4BX6YSH04wrrQkjWcfy3KOEz2xdzKMvpoo7MeqOCubHWB9U145yYIU40PBwr@6HJ4AIvH4XbsYQJ4@@nHB0vzvs4KStH9e7rZj3RyajKZbE5YvX6ZHCSHyXoX7lNMydMZhbI0nc3L/WSm0FteqtHmTAwwze51qhf01KL9hSblJ@m8lqWkUHfiuQ0u4vnQKpwOppM8cyNelsRQNH0j3hhCUhbi9Gw0vu4Lda3H6oZ0VSlX6is617puD65H4m2nM4oqDUqr36YG1wvhOtZRZu1WvGBcC@10xRxXRuaUXVajnUhrrhipdjM1LC4L8/GiEFG7Ujh9LUTbopaf88uwxudb1O2sOYw08stxnJ30l8m00e9GPR66m04NYnm@fysWG@mr/kAP98LjRpwLziZFUVsOr/LKU2mUbsx4jzbKFSIzSqkVZnMh1Bn35LxyW2@3e5lUbT5mjVutPwp1ylOzF9MjweA0KQxHoXBhauqxUip5FTUzyUI7J9@0zdtlO1ajzLzZjLaKfFz2zKomH5xmWrTBtBdF6aoxj@QDTTWvFOXCqDa@nF7WZG06zoSkanMS0gc3uZ4aCOSvG7N8t0TpoWKnG6uPArEMv@Dpq7CqToLNeKWklxfT1FNV6KT5RkroRZhU@CbLjsrVJV@dler1Tk3rtCZR44qVb3PMiKre8I1kapwrTWJss7IsxC4LjWk6XVjMegFxoCan/U6wfBOZlypCoXNNB/Pc1Cx7pHRVpkfForFst64KNxXjFrp1uSiFxOUi1U7p4lMmbZTrJbqij4eN0Ejpa@2olFb5Yq0QMgvjZH7euY0XUmNBrPXG6rjZkTtTU8qM6By1TI@vWz1hnpNWcy4bKrWv6VG2zpvR5CDYoEei2BvLVWM1uCytBo1pb9CPVy@ZjPB01U@1w/WsxpZzRqiiLKluMyVKq/q1yI5r8XzhtpdNSmUlnK4JWu0yP1sEAl1JrM3DK3ZxM8qFpAUfYkrV1E3Zc10M1D0lTypVU4PVARXI5C47g/CVR80JK7okck/RtEefTkOLzBR/KLrUUmR9EpaZWK7pGUYNvRMvl@c9o3BTT3d4eRW7LY/Hkds6dTMrGKoeiBVzyThdGzP6JTeqFG6jkpILzVOXcjZe6KxaMTNbmsqxfGmQKdb1THPC38Szg8ZyOR7EikKtNE5SQixTr496g3Zv0W0YtSVTDvGjnid7ma08DaAftxu5QLGVigym9WD7KqPMas2cZ6XedEpaujJms7XYNNKMBifUbFGMJRumImmZy3I8cj2VStlkZtBKs6og3DzxV@yYazSXTMyI6te5m2vN8JjNnhrqDVPB5XW5S7dvDSOcl6jbRSdSSI51/qq/MItGtKkE1Oo1w16LlZYcnnWkp25NHSUn9FXrZkX35qvcombyZmOshvvR8PhyYTzpqyv9iop1R5zcqqTV0oiPXHWlVZQOs0qzmxbLfLcYYJKtQb4s5PKzwaolTAKj/NM0z3O8UUt2e5dyZLbQPGIwNitRzUrnZhB9emJ6QqUbl5LjVr1WMANNjp52G6XwU6lrGDm@VZBSIUmZZlLdy/EkfbvkmsZiNW1GerK4rOkBJkstKt1ymx@pAyNn3PKj1U3uVilPA5Gb6kiMmv0xO5HYUltkohWt7sl4avJlb7CMtKfCjAfLULsuaGwqORpVqSo7ic5Sy7hhKpfGVaWXLialZLIUC1xrgWh@nL7ML/pSu9Wu5PucGrrtpYORam/ABPqpSnZQC00G0VolGiqlqWZveV1n@5mYxA45OT0qLkNavBRIRej2vJ6/HjWHSkVOJzsLMRXkm@o82uFEpSWsIlG6zHhGw3hRSTKhWoRqmRmzVcrNgx7lqlAO1JZL/qbHTYOc@NQ1PHx3NVxV2wKnysPSU51ttqeltDQatSMpvslUUw1mujLmnFaqUfFMTWEzpcUsNx82OoyhZfJarLeo9NO1mtDT@kFN7FWTC5GZdTq319etqjK5uZ7k69FeddXnRuG2KdYj1YVJPYHJ056VWrneIiMa4qg@e1IuF9ObNh1qXU5Krf7MM4rfdmdB6abKlCqptshNC9eDqNmqLLRyURZlehKoDmhq3qqtVqaQVLOVebm7ENurVVJKGU/s4ormSpeFzI3piWdzyUy12eB0uVq9LGWS3GRenpduoh5h1Sj3w9L46ZaqKYoc0G8bcjTFBI1AK5xZpfnRJTO9TE2axWac1dhWvl0uX7FDmZ/w0W41E@mU@U4yWbxaFkWuXatptatWk6p6lJvb2yZdbcqluFgq1JtquDDTy51OlJuryWuOKYQmvXlpkZqXp9POJF70dE2BC6orQWDrc7lEC3mQnRglTGe1dKVmLANPq9HTYJZRb9rxpHYZSaaXYn8mzFZMMjPz0EZuMe9HJC0WaHYXl2KXLw8GV/XUMKjNtGYkHaaKcbGstHvpYTm@FK7ypXZuagqNfi8keQxGGzWvky2jxS@lSz4ynLWMrgydT9TCzVQ6bsi3mdiVLnmYGJ@i@E6Zq9GlYfimUuyr8/Si3F5mYMoRY8UaE1aXSnsaGyv5KyN11Xm6isUGrV5@DAVPh7dDXmp5Uv2ecC3KFer25qo9ztambXp0fVOO1lp5T2wV1C@feHV4ycWXzVWVYQQxPpgVpougVuJjl7GrKi8XF5V6SxQGkUbgWr5UVlRGiQ6ZpMjOZ3OF9izDqVh2IKZaFUXPtPh8VFBrHE0vOrdmtXMTuwpcMtdMYzJnAkZ5TjNiV5GW3Uq3G@hTqZlxpXUa7CzryZvJbmNU5y9lutKpF1bqspQNGK1kJS1eTedLrbSU9OAtX7pMyzVeYsEsCUcGTb01XqVmPaojLkrpVCx6G8iDBBmGHJ93Q5zAG9pgMaJL5WleXoym47bumSzouue2uwjHh@2hQfOlUrNSmGf1sFo0RgoVifCBfEfXokb9abIspM3MsN2SQ@l4e9Cr5rt0uSlexa/TjduoEK7RhSch3mlEGL4U7vA0W1cnMxNGJH4wpkpLpq/zsqBz0Wn1KZydTj395WxqerTb6OVVrDMYp9kZz3mCyZ76xC3aRZmRKlFhYFQ789lNrgMWotKetRQqd9vSgldSXmzk29XymK0l6yuTTsU7/E1o0NVZURFn9aAZLhaEQZQXM9nb8SiTLzwVmK74xMxZWb@@DubyLBUVPSlT7ct0@1q7VlYBTkh2q7HyvL9KT4YVUcgXAhm9W4/0G1ecnIVhVHoqMVo7d1m67ffkIS2qSrVRZxjqNhLIdm7qT@ysf11bNdVFXh8UkzU5eCMWFLV202Yz1zpdiaZy1@lR/Ta9jEVqutwTmoNYU5l4LoMqzyWVUoSKCjMh1e7QLUEKstHFqseNBZq97YzHsTy9ihgrOqkY81FssIr3Lids57aiXjaXY/pysritpW7YqeBh2RqvUdfmqha@vOx4rpaXrcJAbhVEnuYmy5GRT02F4rx3HUl6YhrT9GT77eGiVBtonSwd7fVibCMY7ITMp35taVxXqHamlA9GM0tzIWbH08oilteSkcZy0boOhca3o0U11ojUwwt2po6zKS03CNPqjRFVFs38IJcSsmJZNMqrHj@hIqtppZCLZT1hgevWureMmKWfGn3ZHA7E5tVNsBGh@XC@Wpvf3maS9CQqjrIF@RLGxDlXXiwbo@64d101ghKlVrueQmQVWTVuryt9pdYploe9@SAaren59ig@XXW1ulT3aKtWoadeZmoTObO6AYGL1OPhUUvOtjrSTabOVCkz0knOwQZnUyVpOaALYeZKVJjiYnIZv5l0IuPuuJ2e1buL8SjSiIbVqbCKmp2n8FRoRbvFSYPme9350BO4pNTGanmTvQ7ppcpcK5k1VbhiYoHS7bg1yU5bnkn6Ktcz0x1G6wU6pfnUkw6DVRArt@OBSu9qlCqML6@N/HUgTjVz0nIaG11GLj01GEymI6Maa8sBeUZ3aLk9nwnjCcNVMlxbX/RauVK/0g/EaM0jRefmVeSp2K3dcqYWUmjKWEb6c86Tz4IFkZG64YanbWrMBOYizM0seKUMggFDuWk0eDOtRsetYFwI5fS2orYX6qgdkK4vo@M5L12NqJSw6ofkVr3TryxW8358HOpzjVkrmbtROsG0og0Xhs5G4leBNvdUm@jBqqnVSi0@pVxPOE6cexZyKlPWGzOqP6gk@53c01SctUPVZCi5vOkzoentbMQqq5tsNzCq9ZJDcV7vhFb1eTDVv2SV@kTSJnqAZpptJTuOLVp54YoqrrLCchi7TtXaodbVKD4OyoNxo8Ysx1VJ5G9vjSlb6A5K12y/EG6nruPjvGgkhWgrLhZH9KLSq95G0n0hxFCeYWFCB9IlPljM3njMIi@Hn6QVWzFXcVFZVlpSrzGYJbVSf9SaVlJ5OsUGZpeL6iSYr9PBKZeaxDJXeleXKSEbTi5a1XLEGN4mzXZIrQVmMe22Jg1uAv3akOMnTCQGOrjc790uW8l6al7qVvINI6kMVoJHn18pl4VcLqVQebFTeTKeOFWcJkOtaql7/XSd1AfNcM80CuziSaCXS6VaTPP8spssGONKu9hQClFm0k@Vo9fDfklpqTUpeEXx8ej4JkorDb44ZYRQLRnKPbUv@afCLFJXx4rJN7O3rFmpg7IrhFtVrTufrNJDRlwEQ9kbozroa7fQW0crKjDN17v9ujhSFvN60WxfBScNdtyey@OIwmmeUDZerXLsIIgnYeEbVZmo8tXAvGlUZlc6TQ9XkamgXQpXElUKaINkoR4pBrjLy24m3mInTyUhECuHpsl5oFove5SwoGUKg4nMpMf1kXAtwZShE6mNikyjIrUGt9P0TXzZoFbdnhhXip25epUezzPj2ajZWgRhetVslwyjUb8x@4VZoFeMyr3qsN/M5NLXfJrjjGhVSWerY23a7k3m@VCYGuWCN6NytCgNIuNoQVh2r6ZavFZcFdLDfMjTVYoxs8uZ8lNVHj1VeqbZe4pK7cZ1ke6korzCPC2j5s2wQxtUPjbJXoaE6KowZKMtZTKbTvvVuqIWlrXrMrA5Ggg2L3t0Uutc18x2Py/wN/kWWPpFVSg0bopa4/Im35/2FUoOgvimaf3qsmTkbjLjW3ZeqC97EusZV6/m1XA0LMZ7nll4UhlOM@FwJzopVma5jKZHFmXQ@oPaslYS6pUyxU7K3ezYUxRZNqaXV@1ZqJ4UbiK98lych8KZ5EIZxmItZnFdvOSvYz2tMJ@0iuzgmp7fxsfGhGtx9SSvilUq9aQFl5mFmWXC2atI/uZaGEXm/ew0UEjOG51CxIxXxE4n9DSvz8dCJceKzcVsHqjlqtemEgov2te34ytohTDFDxbX2ahQDgl9RlrdpvWc2lNaXJKhi3Rg3mpfe9SB8lQRPONaIBfUIllmUeNgZnybmhb7kV5rJHcuU/n4kOqH@KynaUQKt5Gnm6eypN@MPNEJqJyYWJ9dl8Ek6ZmtZmhxLca77KqdjnW4Xm7FZq/oZCifn8YLgUCxFC91KaMRnoC0PM0DN8WMHLiutZuhqSdTySz6w8Ztq56el2O3XXZS6zRmRTwZC9LMXKyO6q1lJbdoSUIkO65nxRTlKVzPjWpcE@uZdlana30xFxqN85e5S2F6xU8XWcXDDAqt5expOhFixbLMCbqSq5vDJB/sxsbBBV/Qkk9XbWqZ57JFNh1rx/SxxBdHlZYxMmYdTZSSoafwwmPWRzXpKpypN2@UUWtYqeh8uhyIGkJm3JhEblujRW8mZPtFSjTjM15eXFYippJa5qSbVvm62G8wS74WK1Zy@oLp0bmnBjMz6VasUWsOehVdKo1g4PR0W6oak0GlmEP1muK0YYGZt5NX/djASF8ysVJxUW1JFQ9zna2PMgFjpnvo4aQayKzUbDEozqOD@vXVhNHTs/7Qc1WL0rejlDqvUGGzH@xwxjheF9lut01r2frKMMqxVs9zdS3TQj1wG03lV2yzF9T602E31p1czp663fJTr93IQ3PeeIRIo/xEDa6v8kZUjPNsv5VKl5LqTGOK@qQuhiYltdsKdEVPd5EpzJ8CV0xuVOixlcpwtUrxRb2jxDKTXjnNLUetWJsKZqtM/zYoaMVW5qmbG05HfLq04IM3at7w3IQqi@mlHotG2FB8xhnB9mTS9sSSsuSJBofLYSCVnUUydF@vd6hs1ZPuqCr0gvpthKvQRqhfkU2jFW02svF6OpfOl66yN2Ip3ihwNzee7nUhnU02I8Wr4Th01WWNFJ0qD0eNADUqpcd92jRjU6kh5YzspZ5ZDG/H15Npbx6dlYzuSrniptJgwoqcNu6UlGgked1@CleZYLZMZ29XshKIhhdxqs@L/SIt18c3nZiUzdNdeQgT6AzI//imPNV5UTeG8Q7UvLxSoulWddDW8/KwBhTKvanGi5O4NB4KwVuqTjdiuWhHvhL5arc@iXZ70k2zGIyK0wXMX7uZ1ZWYoaHVW93GcMrcRLJguoZCT4XOcHI9q7SNejjTbpZqIar9VM@IbCFbKrVvzT5bqTKD3MxsRWP5LMtPUuNKdpnqpQrzHN/q5D0jT6DZ52e5dlLOtvucsVjeMnFGT4ojKjKKlFNihjXn4baoh9LFYTXIyQV1US3GtEm9VgykitlrUR3rTOo6uT4i7WV8IoWXAzGZvGwXuukBlbxOZ0aBtmjwdcUzLxCwVE7mfv@ztwoRdF0hYNRMlfr44zqGYG9zcfbOxhNk5wn8evvevhPY2Wd3IwHRfr8aaIFyvI4WfkP41CqEPNv04w8v4EeLZy@fLfrY9XYC5IL38UAn5GML4t6DUIeOM2/I@Cgp7xFAnniSJyj4ORh5PfkXxin8gAbvGiWwibxR5yK8cX@VNsIRvM8H3seTeTjbeeTpYnepwQRCk3GKCPz0On6Bd1X4DjKSR8DZas596LE@c7aXH4gzNIXsNOLw@R0kq70rBsa0j8JqTRy/2ZuBIhuyrB@svfMpKY5mY0wkTvb3QIrX9E7u4g/eEz7hQIIpccrEmOrz/nigDmcikpE26i345eoJoXAIBaGswHfWHp9sJEGTXXOjcI6hOGNvTWVtsUn2SsIbdJG9FvGOnk6EfJvtrT4iNwl48enUcfZKStHJZC2F1iYfk7vIQ0JJMGeTO@XhTPF43KYnYXpYjwtHfMe6z7Sp7Yl4Zz6Qt/bpE1Rev1qPP7SAfX9VEdVUhR@qTgOR707vvnNCNjNcd6AJp@32p5nAm6q@GyNieeImex3xdRR@Ssy9yCmpazhzqQn40d1mVwJZBfnFpw/TSOjsdTqu4YcPeAuNM9t3YrcCXyht2pMl/pT6QPiJH4Hj1@lPT@1NYXiE5fbDBxInWZEWLUgyXDj5bJ3Kq9rSzixZII/rupzvoLxw4Werbu@3QK6heiCTj/izWDqAWSAWe/fA0QX5vIIAJBOqcLgkKJvnoHgfH/cZ3uUEfVynrXf8wfBYbsi@O48mksguPXA5RzYo2QMDue0dJ0jsnYRfeiOuBBdOK@nDaDrRyPNnv0WvzRH8Jc9HjZP0TU6/McUfyHYhFjNDWhONWwAHnvFecDPOFHabZt0W2PGNvHyF64Px1ciHW4BgnsNf9wXdiF8@wPj6KsnzwfpUrAuZquVYaZFh5yXVcNtNDYzDe1o7NecpIn5wZxBFHome7aSOIBXX9Y3kCSRPOHP4RvIQ454abyXrkIw/IPtGsgTJ1juRh9NVSLee9L8BYGIvTxDXR1N9NDlJdlkbeuCtQJ4the1CHs@asRsRQFbDWO2xnx/ZW6Ogj1brWMK2J17QP4lYWQBYpF1258H3W2khqXjLb5clFztlWjxBX9BXC7OdI4HFj6QkULu4fPfJHn60QwD0P1Cl6HX6unCrtTcV3ZMfPww7A9zawKwg@vHH9yizBXFf/tiHtfRZLYT9cHdqaHFri8f6vuW2Xa1MKzvT4Tz21jG72m3tI7Gtx7pTBrYqxOpb234tSkofygDEH3ejscuTG33axtwZD@h0oz22fLS6xdf5GHglPdgjivRIL@ptg/y3c5XDcg85ORiRe1tlgfcJ485esdPYQPv2oS8AesPNF3LG78mM3Ut/bmW/rTZHQB/p1IQ3Z5ai5cE0vLAJPEAeZ7Xrrk6wkB07T614/N1OaR@Z9AYyaz@9R0BgngMNeGRbq/H1mCgpfuudVNDzTCDkJS7mFsjzlk1rZfUtfPpv0Lkw4@whe4o/ZbavktAB1rwC39Qb8@viZZd7UT1L0x@u3J31UrPzkxPTiF7LE5G6TzBKniIGbTZuOvv/i7v@rzSWZP9z5q9o8SWBBBBM7tv7/HaDiMoeFRcwice4BmHUeQGGw4DKu8nfvlufqu6engHU3ffDnntuHKa7q6qrq6ura7qr1K/n9dC/x5k/4@FL2DtRdrmuMINuJPElIvhrCaOfFbJkF9YvVYLjIIE1wzNLEgchXLwoxUfrr8wbc@xS5vZSCwxUbSbLQbMANAVkKLut8trm2olVp46@eDUxxk0@tsKQQVSkgkz2Tc9V59jO7fPi7b61oaOYI24JbrLDwhwbyoIbY9uSGWzaFbtXGGZhMvhJc/o2DHtZYzBpg4EhmAgdVCkv4aysWSXmZYye0GmjV93qKB9m3d2kNyv6Fa8r9ALGp5ZNEPHulqfNJqaNY98EESe45XKsRoTK3D7AYUXRPmoj/R61rQn0amEjo/ERk4wjV2o9zytxQj1kqp0hDoZiOGRrvZXBezsQqLNDG@04viWPwa8FXgaJ4amjW/7pbl2CzaAIm9gOujkFmdu01GxtZYDGCvyvf6yurE2j8dp1MFzzh/dkVF/PvFXlDyUt24aaTm4Kv@OgcKV58FlrEz6XzYcQSUxopICtOPQfsqhDljOiiGZynsSk40OLZQ8xiPnceN@/75HVLxFbRmH0yP/OaLNQKk5Hk5BLNCKOXad@Bj/jeKolvkWkdwyanC2GE9fJ4n6BvJ3JWclCWQykMgIs5xwQF2jJCjfzLZPB@IFQfZ704tKLin6newciIHs/ZTtFw8WS/MuLzNAj1hpYgcsr9NiXKBMjPjsKFGydRDP@Td3H7zIe5A0fcYXc632KxweCUdIPwxGEHEdB0X6LGCCMf9Vq79WazaJOcSMn1nHKXc4x44ogB6zjFAz2GC9OqyNcoAzKK3QWsAXfdgyc9S/zCGg1mzAVHsBO4RXiEUoPCmX@NdcNWz8n1ZklfN1J/4rAy5KO6jEiOwq8i5tlnWYF08xUdljx6lludLpdBII49gchUVz1@30iWnjxKmYHHsERg/@9xR9dAOelJV7KC3PlhUR5UcqFqLhWsXs3jittuJUyq3/G9X6pTFwtP4drW1Gn6yccXaoYjh26N5@qGxVpkxbElXfsUIpU2oKtREHBKfn7gtGXkpVEGyvgtvxCyrV8r@uRt1Qm6n5K4sdfTw@QzzEY9JXFlJQWh0H/D3E/2hLWsAphlaQ5xpvFTialdohodVIgNUFCzNN2ZzuG8r5sNA7PmczO1qdMUbuk/simyZDcbHMTa8EccbjEON8z4x55JSE8XLzigGCYEDRlZu6OaTzTjWcOWNRaMWg9Eyk0OcGpa@kpvo1j3T/xj5nsSeJMvdXFha@E8kfpvNy0SDKIle5KZjGbktpkMp768lJ36olVJMY9S0NcrCROQuxAu3fQFBanL/dBbsLpsLdi9YSrKIymmOO7LdGcjiuUjfguG0IU/vL@sfbOO@gMyCrs@4@qApu6w@H4vcRlm4kfTSKaAz51cKyi6WjUD3RcN/XA1zl0fp/133AZIYboGA1Fr44LolI/jyd9OYYaFVUDkB9wzzAuiKa3yG8NTzBSNZNqvQkI5KToVYYzjkzMYdDW5cqLr6aI4woF3Kdtn0OEjJzMHvY8wEoreuZikXT1Rub3cEImEHU85JiHCLW64Xl/mwbdH9UDtV4q/aVc@lB2WGZc1aXih4@q7phIpmC9VC6Vfit/9LxqOJrJ1cZsNwdYHwsAmFdHWOg/k2z690il7FVoxeCKEZn@kT@@93tFz2v6PfYBX0@ZIxDlaeRLFGWO84o3ZFsh3j2Zu4Mor2jbdQf1gr9YnyV2bZcDa@Q93CEa@eNBMJGbRuF90AMDzb2pm7DfDx/YEY0rS8IPNBr4E2LKu5xKksRxaTUtbLtwuFjiBhI7cAC/6/Ce40hrNpCdGiD8Pl8A8hBEERBcZJIu3qGE8HX7nWAAcVpAAKIsxRwwBFDXetOu/yQNHhPxL9KgdMd6YXeKyLwdMzJrpP1Cnis03f1xQNo3ZjCPCjdzaKcBbh/WW6rV2G9/qTRrip5Pm43P9b3anto9V@3Dmqo2Ts85iZc6bByRdmmpyskevT1pN@u7Z@0GvchUWtQywwVe5eRc1b6eNmutlmo0Vf349KhO0Ah8s3LSrtdaeVU/qR6d0WJ9kFcEQZ002uqoflxvU7V2I89YTTMvbqca@@q41qwe0s/Kbv2o3j5njPv19gmQ7RO2ijqtNNv16tlRpalOz5qnjVZNoWPeXr1VParUj2t7RcJPOFXtc@2krVqHlaOjVEcbX05qTRCf6OVujais7B7VGBP3c6/erFXb6FD8VCXmEYFHedU6rVXreKh9rVF3Ks3zvAbaqv3tjCpRodqrHFcOqHNe9hmu0LhUz5q1YxBNnGid7bba9fZZu6YOGo095nWr1vxcr9Zam8o7arSYYWetWl4hLyejJhjELSqn592zVp35Vj9p05pxdtquN05yNMhfiDFEZYWa7jGDGyfSW2JSo3kOqOADD0BefTms0fsmeMrcqoALLeJate1WI4TExLbbTXVSOziqH9ROqjUUNwDmS71Vy9GA1VuoQDCB90uFkJ5xrzFORJc8krB6RnLzPJyqvq8qe5/roFzXJglo1bW0MNuqh5rnNJc5rdD8J7cnP@DNf@XTrpCng8RXG3s1svgkM0wmfn9Gi87vyY93iTJaaGwh/dRfQXmtuur519Pbq2B4E2JrbpvJF@xBdJtHeqQcsqJ@857I@6w/lHOD1dWrq8@VK9rntq6ucvmXtEyQ8VwLHYX1qVo53cd@2OnxNj/hW3IZtfNGx3rPS@Bl19fyxjofcmptrefrZri8CMDGTaSTEhCwHjQj32rsDJWDkj8xJ31FnDEj7SwynzfDiP4Z/ox/yNrgvCDlLOcW1tawh2UykPlEWfoJCScF0ZlB@BxAcMMoi5Hv/7jNllx02PJrB1XOtOG6E9oG3mZzzzS/9m9TzQvp9kws7pqysWLCwZsw7RDMkH9plik9LsUx9ywrrj3@kzPUMCIyCnOCii@y6tMn2TfSHPFFxVeY27ShxDkdyHHla/0LNnOl9Y@bqfeH9r3MLdw6R24bWu8uuN0l/zm8lAo0wQJsv4glwUw@qa6tOW3IKmN70lZGrPo7VHoIerSmYqm@83lZR4R8CRfstqfFeBw8utSTGj5oVo53z/b3SXOC2o@///aX/970dMT98eRrXv6eAw/yXjJ3yYp@CMhM4yJnllTJ7tmfS5bjZPfB6KEiskqaQeOXHTJpbeRMsREkv4a4gdDdCBkGhkiykUGSgHFG4X6@v@IZeV04M7UAZBNdzaE3g84jW/gdMpVYBroSJbM/41F7xD@Abae/meK2Q1qAtIj5g9FkRpJLmwvWe5l9E3CA9zZ8rRhVihkjx6OOOYMkjIHO5CgMuIPPv7RsO6NIdi0GGvOVh51bEhEraSpMkhZOuUQoTsPIzGB5GdCbr1re6PFcJwdCEVI9VCYtYuO@bVkwyXvE56wnhoZ8ubNNQ/TmjcW0peBIzWmixP@fTB3jzgYmRQ40qBRgc/LI8tmWsBP609uc@lMkFVG9AWdTS6z@TZK7qDsayqYJia5/mwwySmDFCWX41YPF4Zkq56aKZWeCTf8vfjD8/yBPFsDfog0nQY@5xXo4GE79F3KSoQqvaPfKTAkezIkx55hazE331XkM5pc7MHe2Y/oY3qN8WCIW6NGZmRfnklIsu4ABEHL4Ndz5iwC@PInvOrRz@sRz95V86R8Pu4NR1iTkMkvFHNzLPNtceXNEDj9y8gm/pBx0R8iv8onjPLLOwIaLtNj1TL2OMgLjfZl1Djq99o6dHnaWs2iCDWUzw2NxKumpZSb/oz5hFK8yPVP6i0zR5cm@7OcQ5BRKKHzzBcQoED775HZYs41w7oDQhf1GpBf28iu9iiNbJalAXpdVm8NzRJ0b3jNjKdKxNBC0AygB53VP52y69icPWC76Ap1jiMTQVPY1hzEBEu2LtGaEUb65InGdF9kHSz27KSGvlvqz4Y8hEir74uIyNYqJDFBuCNaiOu5wMqj@y/qdiZG/B1t3kvjrQ46r0pXvlXDN8c6dsGCn/zqKOUIW5wOsS1qHYi51uj/wMmNkNHgoBI/0h3EVdM9NTiPaM3DGukVG/6@lGwLISuoMrMp8G1on0oYsZNuvjfmCJ5m79ukcT9rPvE2dIuLoDQ7MajMIJMNuwiHN@dnG9CXC6uDw6QZZTg8PxevOdNAZ3nQGQX/Gp07/N7wbrkXDaTQqjmZeJpNJegMRCBwhUoj2ia@@BMNe@BCpXZoOcCS1Ts5ap0nHn@P5qornS6m/Eg61y5i9OfA3iJkUhTcTGhp/U810/vFx7O5hP6H2tLBba4YXCEw1ZgEivANrGR@cnKkDf@iPyR485TOX6ijo@kNSH2RM8SnM6E40DarvA3tLY1f7sF3Ys7Op/ICdOta352kEGloeopWlqUgEj3VaRfjmZyTqjk@wON/huF8941S6C0c6GhCcpjA2xcV5M@3nPeRu/FJvH2IzLhtz9s3QsmZ8ffAliuk0EGctdWbcGU5mxBQv7bwhsp/z3RQVBwMiiN5ydvKmboCE7D24/foRdRXJ47UW4BWEpqof3CNZHLvhXjJGfM5Wu81ivm3q@Ip5SV9nVEdi9Lx49PLIGVrMq9/@R7V9yK467Xe6tMNSrSmaf/hAduBuGE1Q9biiVGm9XC4Xyh/goj1rVYo8EfC/ySDmefXj00azTYzUIfKNYNg1E8znpF1yGovYUUDqLur9dyhkU5805vp3Zh5McBPHN7MpXywyGxka@24H7l7qYZQ0h9klC5d8OObEYYgGRSKUmI6EFUEPkKKPlSQwOdDznLpMJx@TpcXSydH8uMF30NYnuerje@h3bszvSAH4j/yOWo15Z9DTYe9pTAb@wFIfTMzq3pEKXjrnmWWY@FJJON7m38JKIu7lXDg9H2ckImQPGET33THpls49iRyOsJiQWCQzrJtytjed66Af0Bwgurp3IRYcUVdmINgF4WZE83jEba4dLEhMy4JsBTS7euHAVhWqPM8Gg9PvR9GsG6rVW9pmY6cVjXy/x5kSpiNJBYDyIs3yPq0cEiZuI84R4K2W@NzkmJQNUrKQ7pv2ETsWsf6uZcw90xuSKhNesH2Hbb0Aoh61JjxJkbEtu2CHnVf4zpvjYe@QQKBtDoxYEuiPQIzy@ChFVNF4s0DwE4tLHuGo@jze6TiAaMjJiKJRsgCw5Kuunyww4NF3/ThXQYR02xKQCjFoiJE4WfKc8IElf6C/OHeKoGlZ6SN1bpazzNwPkEJTfAOhug3xLyoXDcfkG6HP3wjnAhc@IiQvwUvXLM/XpFo2gYhTc30BzMJCmB8WwyxomPpjZX14zwHb0IrFQnoh0aBD0o9gRNz9g9CoXg4r1w/lA5Pt/W0/vEbeJtIUhA1/Zvl4YN3XvANLMNotlSCCyXxTW6ZLmnR9t8nYLmqL5oe/o7aMx2Ln21AGShdsy1zimGWK1y6eTvyIf/SM4sdMInkVrI5U9iqQJ29JdwNsRoPUbzIbKp6ZOInj1teYk00GiSblVBNNXLLJdaLJuhdHKk2NLlpA9eNvsmfGLuFTSTwCatsOUMkbdB5ld1PiAHTspkHKyEREvPVLLSCoeNFVNqYdql96cYjmxGd7wWF@8hE8PvGd@a8Mp7wqJfMdPJqje6wGuFaifMZhwIdZ3aGcZgP/sOGfc4YY3a8tbjJ0NJXtsBR4iW6PcVcr62LJbajVUUe@GqJWhIXNRX3BPMBX@gz9905lNYKCS6xUQlhdrQqJ8Rx6@YK2sjIsRg@WvHhl5l@OgqMR9ER/85ExWQay2cS8MprbwpTHOd1NoPBewDEmT@J/RmTXyVusKI5qaMHgQxpTbeT5j7Q942/MDILXH@ux1i8lprHVHpr4ixjzpVk1kr1YWju9lCyq46wqlgtPVTbMtnxaWnn5asOsgw8B@k6qO6w7gpNYs84swW8jYRlbKcGEg52G3UA0VJJtjtKVtvkFCjg55Ia4fKpXnhPKXPcwvYx4iZUzISRZ5xfStKvXkshOAOW8RCvwf9mA47ijO7GX1itLPT3syyTCwjLj/pRY2Mpm3J8SC6nsDPvTYmFyGVrWcvu0XCRGQliAQ4l6x8A@JVcHmYJHt9ZjqhYTNLt0Y5n7/ewCah2tqn2d3pypZFmkU5ckcfCfRxmYVR1oNCGOxLwLOxqXcW9pjev@8Hs2IrPuvd0i7WSSS4KMZjoRATptMPAYXeaQMts2II0tTjC9Zx7I2U2OaP9WNiy8B0XWrtu75O3eBFizqpRy8walid4fE7@1kPjCfBaFeIu1MZ8f3p4u01TjwFM47qF2xlvwxdd7hqr3DlXJ3jkjlGTxEkiFF0EqvADSmgNJT@wPtF7y4@oYeer850B8@zYPg//8nTZSGgZp2l4AJzb2wQ@d2XMwV8jYWuUzdR05VWYbxHbyczD@SMPgvKB39mucfnnXgdft//xxmM7KsZSzSVlZQJGlanWerDzIYq3N@11dz5hKvLct/ri@C@xOYPX5kZY4xroxjhLf2Y9Aq8mo@hZYPP/LS/iXd4Y1OR@E8IQbhqxl71@cDkUwQjxMclXMNnAUWXIfqguSjHi6NK38eLeajn6MhKdLm@We7ckncfg4TqcydU00VkLizBYuVk5mtTL6bdH27Fn8qwvxj8IR2Tg3Cwng@gP48cUplVLpsWma2lq/aC1buJ7N98u121K5SV4@yd/MdX2duo6L6TSph/6DXv2fgqz7Ykbg37DkL4yMLCHy9UIi8aG9o51bajgdXPtj7yVTXVoU8Uf2SMsl1/NWV1WlS1tmHRkfXrEup@/zNUqYwRCESE1H@F4TyeFOTG74yHwR4HTdXvgw5NrFDFCwj3bgd4Y6VL5eMG/H@H5h6@aRvhOXuxhDMOwSoyPfcX9@l5zUPV@X4ETyE2zdXDz2kGrg1FTkY0yaLLE1s7PknlbeLjFwrFXDtTbShoqRHXwMfSeWubaXyDDPLXaBvcR6esogIiFehlJveFOgn5bRjeXMnI4sK@3QvICVi8wt6@V@gbk1e6m59R/gZHpAPedZWw96gd14VqmlN/nePwE)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))
- Gaot++ (140) [local](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)
- Floater (141) [local](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater)
- BitChanger (142) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl)
- MiLambda (145) [online](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php)
- Curry (146) [local](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html)

### Explanation

Curry is a language that is based off of Haskell that adds logic programming features like those found in Prolog. The distribution of curry I am using is PAKCS, other distributions may work.

Like Haskell, Curry supports literate programming. The literate processor for Curry ignores lines starting with `#`, unlike the Haskell literate processor. Unlike Haskell, the literate processor does not have a quiet mode that I could find so all lines beginning with `>` must have either another line beginning with `>` or a blank line adjacent to them.

The curry code is located with the TRANSCRIPT

```
>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-0s
```

on the top line `{-` opens a block comment. `<<` is there to balance the new `>`s introduced. `-}` on the third line closes the block comment. `main=print 146` does the printing. `{-` opens another block comment. `0` and `s` are for Whirl and Alphuck, respectively.

There were also changes in the haskell code

```
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"--}

#1""/*/
```

The empty lines around the main function are for Curry's literate processor. There are also empty lines above and below the C preprocessor directives because of Retina. The `--}` is a line comment in Haskell and closes the block comment in Curry.

#### Incident

`fi` has been removed from the string in the Fortran to detokenize it. `---` was added onto the outside of the Nhohnhehr rectangle to detokenize `+---`. `Lz` was moved from near the DOBELA to with the rest of the tokens at the start of the polyglot to shift the token balance.

Answer (score 7):

## 152. [ChuckScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ChuckScript), 6934 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        >77*,68*,@'_            )(22)S/ \\7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8    1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111111xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# do           x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRc -BkBkBkLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoO4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p se
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclxx"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#s8dggi2M`|$//''         $>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/pppppppeeeeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<* 5>1  s*e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001974

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1rc@tKkhj4@cL7D/wFh1JfkuIDAN@URJ3Dp0SJIik@9by6IAiQIEEAAsDnueoY7260PTOOXbs9nmjP2NPdY2/sRKw/OLy7EXbYERux/urwj7j@OLGx/Q96MwvgS6J0zp3xQiJQqMrKysrKysp6osOb/d//fg8vuqop856iWbQlmhbdNeSJaATpzJz@xMtmNBSmKIRKG73xSFQt85DaozmallVB7sI7bWlDUZUXogH@IZrWDa1n8CPa6vMWLZoCr4smrY0tfWzRmrQ7Wpim8yNtIAcw5khWewBmiYZuiBYJj9B0U1X4UafLvwiJvkhQNyDcpHOi8sPoB4sWtNGIV7smQMZoOlfJ5EvpFxjiNH2pGaaIeATRNDX0TND0LC8KL0CTAMobslZKl09fBHEsfQqk87oizmi@Y1oGL1iypmIQR9fLzXr1ZYwQ3WoUCi99w/RFQFPpwlgYbgWRMqgaWncsIH@svgjByFNJVkSTEiDvJ7TulGQQHfQebYh81wajJM2gMQo9Giq0TAu6TncUvh8UaEUG2AKboEUsAnoB4UrfpGf6CDCY2kjcpMOkVVHs0qYuCrIkCyR1WpxZompCbs0gLQPdU1lR6K6oQIQ1SYIfkNFjc8PLJiBIdTWKhkvQX2Rg9bYvAowqLpkg6lAKyAQNCw04suTF1OB1HYgERtaBcEsegezJltukRd6UUbohiimqXcI/fSX3Gs2rm7mkJzJP80Dv2CC4TdHAwgwSvHRfNERAya8kzzM1ZAtYgOxN01WRN@iGIYre7TqwlSQkpmEKFmYkSIrv@NidrxTcUIx2jCCvW9SeEW5cnVM8HUzR@49H8Eu5XEdUvpyjP@/fo9sWeShq3fDwXjr1c9pk7u9F@M24DtMzninASgFXFJrRdIvhAzoQGLCAQIZHJ7oCk1BQVzYSpo9flMWGcNlQXSgNuqjSLT/JmTA2DKzWa6byQ8i0oqk94Cdk1hiryA@VjrFQBIIGtdJPixPgGog7KSNtSjjc6MtQaCYWyUZFspUTYSioJ5A9h6PLdE1NGRM4iGlaKIDAFYiKGIsS3aIlXlYwCoQjKptqQzTHioVxxmoXSx6Uj9gN0ksyBK2LQCNtAsnxgJR4QF0abdRAQhQAQ0FoJKsY9OM/@vNurwd40oKgGV1HXFt0VxOIGuUJsaCbaBRYTeUVQhbA@TF1OzokMOEVuctbmLw6d5IgRJBUp9pY6dIaJGhMZahafX4C1VGSRMESbSG3Na@fHvFDW2/ItuRCxkd8BwqWJEDSJtkO0J@yUEqCSO0RmQmMxpaUoAN6nnabzHeej4eejx/uRSDOG/Qe7DNM7wgELnhAvODN/Z7ktNJbmtG0eFOTu5Q@t/qaGqIDAu0SUpouqh73Fg6332103N4g6jOP90hOCUFJVrseN8h4BtJ1e4@ElHAnHz4cvYi9mSJgmSIWrK2iR/C6KNA4pE5MmBEvq0F9TrcCjmsjTDMfkeMYHNzwRr689JvYHnuk4UGx1FA@QA0FTUUUdQ8b5LyoJRBuZ7YxYFdGX@BwMnwoP/jce27fZtYJBsjpVkaxrjZkDbWWovexbQGmqKYO2ttA0RV4EB4TlbgFrb@f7hCxJpofFAtRiVPRbYh0B/ToUoxIjbRrHMYPoJ50MKxr0BJuu0KL3Y36DLoAqrRlvlLKijaFhAlt2HyBBlExcb4HRQSR7Qyl7QzZKRKf7awNVdAriK0j0olAR4a6gLUOVLsj@ht5BPBwyIYBbHZd2VBBI34OWAS7SVzXG1qWoEqNQEsYc1oQUfWADhLtdgUTGZNqaILdgxYQGwhFo9tV7VVNswwmHbgFXb1g3q1QmPnNOoX6hpbEKa3wam/M99D0UiEKLwiibjn6CnJiWqCRXjY7xDPgtKFBs0/tf3qZNmlLnNZ1Iw3U9XbpOS0ij0rGMb4CCuhUmnfMR7orG6CdlPnL1AFg8iJx1/cIskXA9643SFgaAiBk4kwUxhYoNxDkaV8W@iC7SJ1qq0e7LXqZPHhtpg4KPiCtkkZiuJNvQ1SQWXkhGW@iCGCJvsYDbSyiOtnyIIW/6fE@Zt4c7UCsrUiE9mDDN8jwQZC9L@Acaaq2AykwcoUWQbZD7HIAg6yOxiC0X0vri1TWlYW4KiIoM9AeUPNB/vqWpZuH0FzIVn/cCYKkMA1jXrQqKgoLYxlz2dJsd0fROqCeTaifzDIFRhh35NmLDBG/VRkOTGoCdphk0ilowJ/GIHUet2SC4iT@WQTeCHIRBU5Q2HcXABKgIDDKI5lEJRdAqdTnquBxBUlVCkKlc/lpF1ZclxccGGvFl6w2Qi1Et4l9gAZfxgDNJYG2cnQ/Uf38zhZv1QYQ887tDg40WfV8dn/48MF96D4BDf/hw0dwHaPrI7p84PpIXAHiQrggukgMP3Fh6B2JgX4P7ue7JeaZ9wGLbYat00LWPfzd4WH4wc/fcc4zhE8vqDrQbAAdwAfgcXtTKXR6va6TKWQ02JG2c59F7VwXDFl3mHDOT3j73eFCmLBBHumagXbsETa27/NklDKgNQTbVeh7DPf9HXv/cP/5vuu7f3b7Mbb3iE91IFOQnmcU7BnaGJpN713kMMA9eL13YWgsOyk36z7weBIBBRLivd6fJbw@3ua2xy2C1vbc37uBqQ5/7oS@QfDN/CGvd8UqoAMbaDANPe7g5wSk3/E@eH1uiOt1@6GnkXK7gTMCMsEkmUbJJAyq2aLXJdWlJqo9SpwRFpQrufxjNd04S7mYsWkwitxhVMjV4whUHHT2XDviQ69tGR2cNU2zUkSi0Z9AFwDI6RVTljYGpQgdNHkkW0XSPVRUrPlrqV6GZiHdNYKqLFqU01yvlQH2FNcFBfkg8MXNTqNkaKNVE2BSotDXaNd@2IWdna2OP9pFTmgEQ8dOt3/DP47@I@yyBwWqJwh0QLNfV54OYAIBsRsfhN4u1fP5EJJ061eeDmSSoMSufdDoLD0/c@wz@q/69RsN7SbGXeFvR1oh5whyUx2b@kbmPnMh4j@xJAklZeUdJt7DAKDRnSLdMZzhgMcQtqt1RGUWiwRERQpas0UQtW8sQtkPOtB9C2JHXGq22BWBskCVBmbSiwDeoGwKG2ASlKAHSJdkk4z@bAoFtapE95RrqQm2KrxrHRJaW@a7uxOuTSxE9EGchhq2PmvXI9jO0S0Uo6HyOqYkm31y2wJ9RdHrEBLbHHUkctsBcOiYqFCBcLwEWXKOvW20kjWNVsUpASONLUEGrJJVnqmRBza7u@jZNiC2iOmI0hh64AxoQ3R/ASyQTBBIqdOR3wIFviDpy@cOMGPc2cU2EK7@KxuT3mK8NTYsRew6z//8B10ogNfF0@fn0HMUhivHI/ANiyogvVlaTlR8IbfdJUtgBmNF5gkbiOtLKAUee/e8snLsRo0KnA4E@rwBhTtfFi4IJ96gpr8jZzblhqiMu@LyuTsRwuJtS9aOrcojkiN4ollOGuY3or@ww@34ODpiKBrfJVjsUStZXJe2XS7ijO9B5pgNjQT69CvoXJrL9HqYCuxCa2zfcWTqS@Uq6/jbzZXDbSFjo3yHE6FXz3fkN/iIZMTekmy7wqAlF5AUfmg7H9G5O7N2dgy51wML1nm@BQbdFehR6rwgMlPyeEcslk0HTcwC/j2chmLf3wJZDsqvHG8BQlYVcvspwkfEQYAagrKD48OBDTbJLxir8J052mD9ny5FmCBpk0HJpASfjw1j87waUFiPROv62/HRniDxk8ndse1Ba4JA0CRJFL9Uc6H1kUe8Egh1N5xvKuJlD2Ht2gE6ABMajGaFN0FILIfN4gSKhdzeE1xsUAQUl7XrHbFdk7McN3pr6GEdR5cFTZFNnRT38uUtjfiy07ZGg9MS5LaOim@v@duFPgE21oGVa3el1gQLu/9vyNFXKCm7541jGxuCEdTe4p2gTfH3ppnQ1yaifd/dcC12UvUVKiigEMmAvvfr6F3hS@KK48jktpuLw51UWYKy0/@QvtQ0oy@qJh0KsmjmqGTyA5ptRbGHAhrFytsybcqKZtJ1cn@PF9B9ME37vluaN9km82qAdMg23buj7SSKNHJ0mtzfKFxe6WlKLNFjeLi9KQFjQ0JN7zy/VsOtNBTHfVFDrYweTeWc55uqfQj/XxIOMqxt4GjPhvMdW2qXOnNGCd7OIPQLcAh3d@YKbILEDDJ2n@@tAjCE/pSfL59/g9bjLe4uWw99TkxmsOkwQjIBDsuwzei/SWqR91Prfp2OeoU2/qVMbBTuUBFBY5P7qyKlQyz3E2NwLPv1GktSxuJY3KlBKp2BiJPh7@iOryeKdbKx74ySMMA8nPFeQS2cDuFXUY3tOb69q3B4RYZK/kVrZqeq0cHO1rEDXQVHFR2vI/bUsb5VuBu8q43V2vuc6@vLmq11t4jEkJ@qkRJftpm2THFTJL@3zPb8SINurzYCG0L9ivJ3kJIBJfu@hZj4rDEPZBzbMt7Fe0ivhoXBfgV7BEpVHpoBHCD7OsUTequ/ToCTSeiRqaI1x/tb3N6lSDuapvyU0gF92pXRTAPjE5d@fKmUXtk@zgwBvR6ZMHGUoyO9NSZhtzVO5xG4hx3lNwu6ClmySOPwNaX8asTwnVZrY/zwS31IaLHJwI9pCEv3W/TWsHJzwUQw/i7By1ExZul4D1kyGP4a@0hfGr1keBaHdO1B3PXalb0X@kefA6fkbsAU@uJIJK/vWPx8dzA2l483gWYa/nYEBxkywPpGPF2GCq/ifWvAeMMksjRVNBmLN3oi9lUUkQdr1PZ9S8kux213Mrc44nti4YuStR52wLljMk6/4dw9AHFoT@cIEO0LasTuBmrqUJyby@duY3kuQHmOR@9i21XJBRzd/GKtDjI7x6q/YPOpfa2v9sW@QWrG6u2tugESadnL4N7LBNDf580hTpYThbTu4/XNTe4qmqJ8DXdRIdrqUdN2D7zmcZFaF6L@JLxzvgMBzuOLY3TQbhMmkQb8rbrTF8fQPJmapeligLy9BargCI993z2WXKy4Tboti0YXc4KyOIKk5Y4i0lMZSBiYm7MDu0ePOorG43qMdyx44Mzy@TXjUYJm7LbkTnnNAuP0/Ra3QOj5UruckS1cO9H7AuBW8XRE3lLlIePUb@d1txxva1uSNZkO5NA7qMjADGMexFJObYbX8VHcXbPlkrN89d1sZceGMf@yVFr9sT2kj463hlacKaSd5GTrpS8rRGeyabfqU/gv6FR7eGdr3hP9nblLshhwtV7E9DurGMFPNpw1a@ZqYeheURUMkaweWa4moPdwTct4NFZ4SzOCNIHzeHifz@ul7Eg4BNJTAWwJRZbm4Xode9WfSSuyaRFYWaLv7uj9z7ND9pB7plO069BFPzzYWMnKkfxMJ2vqanbUu33@IbXvDgTc@@579ZBm3QRUVKBHuhOU34KTZPKw6VxnnVb5EVkihO5lTo/sdUhmnyz1A5nvQi1sgklF@KsZ9moae8lWA@dN/tNfdZ0VkNCGmvRINqEH0lNx1a42Evva9KOdrpN6Wtd5XEGJOKZ9nBjA1APZNG2CDgGbgSx81KZ0s9BIOOuonHXF8FJFQdmgwi5UtOZwdZ9lF5pNTVcTbXFxEl7FWmZK0JTxSAXN1bX6ZpCugz4TyTqt1cQxuBBMtQxU310/XaS7Io5Yd5EwYrEomjYkM@JIyX/6K3v1GATKKELoXiZPFo9upEijFUaWbAmCNgaql0gWoqE5IB5kMrSaY@wMgLCLtr8X5Jwny9pAEgPLRV2YjL2wK5uu04E87cbFz7hU5EiWPPvp2mnrjn1I/ZweMeJ//gPG@9nhm@tngXjMdPnpJcjRM8rVZnAUgtehbtq1P3M52cJltmRV6UqonLX3HnST4lou0hqRFbpE7sQpWaRFpvZVNApw6atqQv2AVy9BbVea1L5nbFuegbpFR3GFOBhzPLjsNb1ksSMuOMIo@zP6B7qPshIQaC7KwpvNEAXXuI1SmeWsY3hzYpjJiZ0xmSSZhIKhcIpkZ/8xdXxCXIbY1XDJ6d1397MQG7ifxfMPjLlkzv397Gds6Bq4p0GjuP8tgxUoX8593g@esD/8YPJz2uV6dh/ZE@VQy/c/V4vVfL2RbjTrwM1nO7N7Bc0Y8WtNgbKgg8qD6qOQtbzAFkMWzS9rj5UGWb0BuMdD7/P0Me4a8HpXAStQh9WugGvfdq5AwDrcjP2F6Lvim@JG@GsARzNJMu1oUbpKBMmRGbe5qUH9S9nCcsHqPgadveQIrlrYoQoJj1x0CrgUAC59JY/o17m0S/Aj8YBi/DKj3sexCwXwag3xGgCZtEoL82uH25nbmfnn/wY51qFd@9vmmOB4N8cI8V6OAXAdjcQopIulZi2/HQnEab1xAyxwA/fvSKRu2UvAbenSnOXGS81EjFfTWVa40q0mPZFNYtyivEnYMkD/kFRHMldqonahUZEF6bRigibvdkE1deYWajZQ6UGyPsZeJBNQadceMCu4amj9tItCWDP1etkpaK6pAFrsezvyPoEjmE1qxzL5e5H58R/9ub00/t4C9x867hmbgbc/dt4kcP/DZQjHwds/Xr2F4O2X9tt3DLLy9UJgOzcrJiIDW8UqbRL7G1k04mcbuce2DdtOWQWbUR4BryeEdQhuZ2vNmTUez10LOA/FBWxHJY16maQnGg8eXMZ5yDBoiuCISZCsxhBnArHMyarOpzFuaoCmhIlFYxEODFYxMFkiDMg2woBuI/R6D0EqqYmsp77vCPTx8THtMgVeEVOxI5vlzD7/Xdj1/YrQfYClbKvljoY4EGUdA8JOnGiefd7HeTEqVk4356YfjsAgsUsQ2jQPcQCIF71Vhx8uaDQ1h1UgHqo4s4jiny@tMTCFVLL4TLS3tiwRBQCRjRvX3r@U8vUkPy5@2pD74GYxuNoIVkewQ9cuIbv7jr637tUHZwsGDQLzmx0ip4L7j3bsy1hJT/r1jgDPy/X8mBv6U13VcOFHAailPSEmFGa4mHejTrkcVEAv1qAfACXUGaiDgigPNN1MZ/PF80q1/mpFO4F0vwRz0@6TY999IOi/e1g53C@kfsnUTIGpX2YKS1ZuUrUeO0WI9QDqSzJ3pfaS0jdSb9urK16nTQJeJcSxX4uYDFYECmSO4TX2dSizAZi1Z39fperxfn6@ezg@uVf3XiX/w67NPnvBAxQucN2bZKuPm96hc4rLNSMN3NFpBpeLEEOu9Va21UJN@33t/faa9NX@0PXC9OXqFFyUHjphuuKEUceKQgXfWLcCeQ8ydlJkVbZN2JJe0DVLUjkkdZ2gQL0a/96khnby8norq7P2dMWkit2RJZtueBX6MIYs2NAmUdB2d5fsEIEOT9Fa95Gg34X9a9IVnJNuD6iK1Vx6VyYjd7yxXDe6CqmLIznQWNKDimO90NxZYd2HvCly54hP3c3o1RrM99ZbB01dkS0PLv6eBbE7CbnxeDED3DGunp55j5MPzkJ1erme3EeWpFfHwK@qptPrLnxOXLpq0Iujc2NADmIg0ufjEcBJ5FETsZUQ6bIWgMjAR/eSiDtchO3kITjqRiH1YF@cdeUetDQerx9U0s84br2YncfV2Kob9LDNqlNcJLDJmJ@0AH@DY/wdH5TVrjjz4GarwwfkDvi7p@2J2@t6JQNkF4CzKL77cjvAUlnwllNr10vpXyiEZHKlCLbrTjIZ7JsUrpGFHgikWLeMEjihDfVII16nPWOyn8KkgzR59dx7VL9pGV46cILt2ZRWaZ@P9F3gQQKCNIkpEZes4KicB3chepgUlDP6mmoXHwtZp@@4YPAB3CQRL72Pow9ZMDew3@6lwDSFKIcELTTA8HeIFE2hl4YU2c99kiyFQwcGQO0MJhW51ycVEHhBck2ffEuvtcG6BtpcTSYPndLYVodJGsTieIfGALQ71NzSNgX@OgsdgWuoxAAqC51SGRTKpwtRVaG@ekBmRlA7aX4MQmZ4/cut9P717kqSwp5N4pmzchII3d51mXd/VjSwZ/aZI9IDPnqGdv/7e2z4JafpnzN/lwkyR589@0pqzoAx5j3x7PdTnC984PPtqweefRXNkW@/xY7z8z5YO49BV9A1A6DAvuI9AnkG6yi1rx7t88ee/W4qdEBiwKvP5/0MEX5uMsHP@/wzs/8tWBN@8DHs2unZN8lOCDYY5J6BPqwh@4wfZOazx0W7yEZ4TH5f9vmQhuD@IxLwc@a@7iPtyn2dIX30I8fIZXqjpRrZtlVWJfFqY7/NQMf7cKXRo2QFvD059rgE3tx0uSNsl330@9/vcTHobn2MhT2a72OUPfK5o9yRe4/e@@RiDlyG6/N9LjChxYD7jpdCwaeH6rBavfbee0A23XvZiouLuL47YKg95oD9Ic4w33//PRih9N1J8CT44L0LuB/uPMuO1Ek8fuCPJQ78n9yPmz03rycU8gKr7u/jPH/gi4Q@qUd5vP7L//FffvVf/oT8/Yr8/oMsy7rZ7cJP69NDegHXUKLxn7gX3Q03j@6OtPCA/Q5mXQpF7hu4uKrbHQ2769/hdqKPH@CP/MO1esX7B@LjeBOQ19cHmto7EfYWexzH7c3J3yO6yTVzrsDs3YvhuND9N3hKROzDp2@Ad6KPXIeHn9YsYlzxhEvTiE8fUojS2h4a@OtrFsCL2ps1ePyjGx38q1n41xriX03APzqQGeJfaYF/uwii9n6eSvnevegdfsHg49JF7X1//H3qb3Fhfqg96O3snZw8PD/7AnfB73xHR84/6Imj1RtetgsIePAFfMd3x8fBk5PZSeDh5I7a@wwseab2Qi4Q5/sDai81O64RKu9yJ8vcbF0l8DkOPNxVS2CoN/yh48BeqJDO@kP1ZmaPg7fo@hUDw/hay6dzlSZAV0v5dD1/Wmzlm1XwNx8eTz598gWhaD4Bf04egKLZz3wnvpRlWfTt40GQ/orrcYfLfqX2ciezJhM4BqJL1F6NpBQIPp48/EDt3e3deXwffR9ZhZ2w3JAbXmqV9X@lMoMAecYONIPts32uCzJLs2KTnbPzGTvSKlwXnCL8sSNwyqw0Y3usyqocB/EjlVjl0xbCN/5HFe2yogE@DeJaM9ZC1KwEz16lcgkYJUh9AH8yy7IzIHPGTuCfVexa9N0jiyqCvb@n7mjX9yIomCDnDrLuYMztlh@iMf3p83Mo9nRHrJBo8uFOnMnWg4v2ux/v75LJpPvhaI8x7@8ZW/W6QhHXEY0wz8@Pj7l0I/34yOD4zex43/fJF/gEV@rEd@w8Pu51T44@3h8GULptCQ8@7jHHH@9PwgF0x3zA8BD4HTO@n3itUcLzwz3l9kzb7Tb@2tPJ1HYRh@13316F4q3NgJftQi@4EJTZFX/bMXstYB7PXfTh87PX6713H7mdXYIemmwTdHH3s5BEh1xeYtMnoUHkwmh2xaLek5NYFN5jCW/Aw5JgO8q9S9f1e1eQjBEEyaKvVCptGPycAEWgTb538cbjvesu9JBKJaPEOxpIxmjNCCTDXpfX@x13fOykEfKCt8s9c2mGm/78vPnn@fx87CGXF/@8XvR07ideDwR7o/A2@@yhjz3HHvQDL4z1@fkEnQTuM7juPN4H7/Oz7Qd3j/fYxnniBbbhQMh/w3/NpE2ddu8976EtpdKRqNfTmYveSMyT8CWdv9QHyIDHFXaHIV8uN@@@u/t0ED6IR@4@PhwED/DnOb4/edihw73QgkONWQp4ittD9lF7waOaiwu53CjwRzgFoiliUNF6dDh5BMZm8ojag2guuPZAHmlg2snxSkjWbY33BKrkZ5pwjfY@0N7nzyA4diDYWh5nuuL@fsaypIWnjzqp/c97/PMRwU8/u5bgjvwR/B73EZnPcn127fPGHffgenbtf@48o1F6wHmJ7RONHB0dRGx3PAFu7sBrD9GC8XK0ckOIaPLCEVb0oz2UDzcw0Qu5SnXEnqyCIbpZAXzRaPQDE4LH7GexfGh24FwnBzuuRCjhO/B9ujsAGwiL4oH4/vCBOsLJIntmyhVw2dWITiQJEXu0aSZpUGjH4n7VN1v@HeQObBeHv/wHk4L@VAdEZErHWWjhFdz5oknSB9sfOoZ0RxTBNhcVBYc3sd8E3QelO4W@@gdqD8oQqIJguEZVXhyL4nQ8noqrKyubh/xgAN1@vH78zS9@/M3/@ONvf/njb3/x429/9btf/@oX8Psr@P3Sfv7yXyejeP/dr//x//LjX/wWPP8D/P49/P7d7379z/7A/pH3/wi//2vD7z86vw04@0cBrj/@3a//5C9/9@t/@Gfw@xfO789e/n78039r///fzh86f/vjn/5HvDkvv/gl9df/5jf4/yf/5q///W/w/3/9l3/9b/7pX//xvyKOP7cd/8@/@Nf2/b/@vV/81//@n/zXv/frN@6/ePf@66/w//X/Dz5fT@fX4PmafP1Un1//jej523BjnQoI1K/@6Md/9g9ATv8U3X8f3PBP@wL25XMA/hA9f9hnWbBz7n/YhPyB4cD4oJkNzz@kf7jH5dTcGhLw//MfGBaMJNaGXOHchPyj3/36n/wl@P7wiQY/B/IfLKM7@mYLckUnGvB2Wn8IwH@xAfOHP/7mD378y//hx9/8@Y@/@WOKo/GEug/0BypE4xNv6EkcxDU7oKJhUGtLN7d2hyPEHYX7LlsT5wI/ftrysnEf7AImgB9J@IedpiumcbCkbVdiH5bxd2L4SH@CYLBYiNEywzu@gA@6SVNHHkuvmQNI3m0Y530jpu1jv9Mb0bf90XMj4vKxy9sOIEkugWgH2cxJlF6jd7JBLSmzgWevPCjayR5FxelmFW614ulZY@PZyKezZ1SMzlTKuRePqAMUpUv5QmP1GrdDl1GjKxQ3@VLp5avzuNEOD1M/5yJxCp7wNqYFHhsgchjNjBwXFzw@BlG/Yx8@R@KhSDQSDYVjsWg8xEViyUgsmgizHBtjo6EQl4xEkolk/JlOUtTJ58DxMXVSzzcATaNCcyE2SJ1c07MgXa1eBZ6pExzuS9nNKKD6HDBNisI29gMdjfv9wWAQbvj0k4s8g/vfLUG4tztXey6O5aIuV4wNxV0uaEgDH11zke7TIzpMH@mQO@oSp72SnL1eSUaU4DLEJK7QgIZ5qpIFMh08/Wisv@0JD/RCpyH3@hZtTbUVgGmaYLevLPqlNb@y6tt0h@fx91MvSEHcvKz3PSw7DeL3KkR5DU6dgX0ywlM2cF2mheM/skSzVBBLKhRKJqKJZDiU8CeSiUiUi0Wjfi7k5@KJeJL1A@MTXCwRBdb6E5FkOAIS4Yeyjybj1J6odmWJYaCfzkGHHZ@yKuCG8GPcWa8F@yfUXleUcDEPPfN0vfRed@UxTtCucOKepSGii4tROLF@MEtBhw@XHIQ5mnNRLp4W6L1CIcsWCi5XBl9A8bNZ1uXq4ks0wbLxjMslkpAsCG4IIvXxLR9jcXeNS8aXbLpQQAwDfAklEIfLNbRD7Bdl@RIHMBVfwmFEQLtcTyt0LCDXbIoSJJZlv7BsJutyjW3yEvAHcGn7LUKIzeMLBmCkgh2ShTCX63QZCdozl6tmwzlJnS3zm067XEX7JZ1GFOck81E7Uxf4kiYXRDLgDaTX5eqBo2eA8elydcCJMuxyCeAS5jz4jcCFq9FVi3e55nY@MCcu14xA88LQ5Xpc@kM6QM/ZGd@3umLPvuaG/RQgqAhB8mycL3ROTzu9XseYp/OnNRJ0fn7GD@Zjo9PrOBE7j3BpGAuChqP5y0vEoMdHXtkddAFB6ougx/mjSCh85J@AMufqYUKjx3MMOoegXcNnDkK4RgDcwSszgmeG79hBy4sEkees03EdgdBSWH3oucf7mQxmeGhTXoigdTysfwxd7OjHccIVi7sOD@Dp@ugKg3PmoVk39LFc7nuXy3uXfPjoikddh@6PHwPub7mPtCuedB264nEX7T0yRGtsqHTo6BnTWaTYI3w@4bE/NO/Hewf7ap8duM7RM@pf6OB9fvIsfCnOv/B@RMI80IWMuLyHQOjRM8McY/XH6gpPeqmzyQQNwCVcAVDk9ArA1hOrek4HAqDFafiB6YPhesrOs8eV9GCHFAhKJu9dpAtpD5173O54yO32uo8AyQfa5YWOpE0n0k7oW@YelTzkPhlyLTPvSQagZ00HkkD5K1qM4aFp8QZOopCkDmlXLOlCbzxSNfmqEfnkD3D@w4NO9Pjk77y6/ru/s@va7YsXZTdzMY7ae6a6uKU8kqSPsEP@mXr@/Hx84iR6Qc/nvC@wpOFbmu759ql9N7LAHd4a20mn0r1aetnPTmepvUBYi2h7@/v71N5x48QVdlWCj6txqxOGjHze47AoDiMG7x@PP/j@RoNageDJp@X4LRDOUIaIawq7eKCrPbiUiGKR9Ghzz/c3vCARKgU4qSMcrXDtYd0TFKh/cdxBa2fo@Od7ZPCJrn6WxiqZVD68xClED39YJ6d83D2A1Py8LCufE@HACZmEQakG4XjW68nv4t8lvrtsVpqVwif2MHGYIJy8v3eK38@5OTcpmcdP0IDJtTy1Z/6gRbmfq@dHe4e6Oxxxh1fFcZ/as/POxb17J6F40OTnew/O@mhPBDwf7PmyELfX3r6mWy8TMnANSSX@brfXk0N/9/L7H/YZxu1eJbV/8vkrrue74@PnY7yeHQfenp@fj1/9k8f6egNmHf43E5vg497DzwPH9v8x3LIVmzmuWNTlxRXv5neP3z3ugTpJ0q5Q1IUdDMYeydCXxsmBSv5E8wD/vlt7HED0g9WbeHxAR0@g44F@DMPce69CYLkkk7FEbI/6PcO8twQEQldzopIoGuZ4tGtSNG3IlzxOGKuriVFwXI4XogHP5fGwSxOHRhsHZ/3RyNn0c@yeDS9yqvK239xkcIkq@oKNjOfvkuO9aQn1qQeH@iyy1JA@wDOtcSW@l/pMfQO4xoJFVrfC7YiivsFllvjqWcL56W9Ny4sLy1gv9c03TutgWkHTekTkGMnxDHBH1DOF7OG7XZPG@WqyTsxevs/jokVNt/dpKnPajmSSVs621sjKe0x3g@ADWrKpgNwc0CRFQjlmzk7@GxusM5aQlEKxlIc4dIqWyLoHJ7bL6ODphSR7HySvkzjNghdiQXDCKQKOgIAOPD0Et3eEewQED4H00RyGS2T9BECB8eonlPhpyYl4h68PEB3RS4KimYDYTt1j54A@eHSSdfKwbHQxE8BCzB1p1UjjbPQEv1N6eH7R3YOX/rxciezBUPqYDq2XSju4oDDsg8dJRGHUtQWHHAvpsJlg4x78ULRH9opWzwrO8Vkz6pk6sPyjI7uo9CPqwiN4P@P8@tHPR99@K3yn340ejryjlIVPn28ETezQI9sgB1ZqlALx0O/khyPrzueTH1Ij74UH3/HAQxaAJZvZptfJG@RcTQEtuAbH9PoXd2rg5@qDv3Cn@oDksf/gNrXw8ynWP4OfDPaJ4n9KcU4@IE0rtfCpR/wx/HCqf2u1MNgZPv5oywujDD1KanHHP6SAHwpE9PkKkBmg07xTfL4HLySuQODriEfKt9/yPuVkdqQEAl6E@i78sXBngePBl8L3Qw9/PPu4uBtD/EMPPFOQjOIF4iGew@vnFe1A3xHw2C7TNek2jTMkbwbkjVKpg9uPB7cHqQ8fFnezwOjBb7P/kF1LAxI/Q@KPNlZjew5uvfQLlpBBe4/rZ/Lhz4IHJu3yyz4fMNmvb8S0KTy4hRDd51tS/Yz6kpyHvFxGghLmrCC2T0ckJ6ORaR5ybLNJjqq3uriXAuKmTUGWHXB7E4wuQ4@ZxwOW/bSqqQGeQGCYcz47Bt7PPn6klkk7i1YhZVQuHZHmsedNjuc1cAaBnPVvb9b6kn7dpYaXOnfV36wXb/M09G3DsY3qSlQTqXCmIdwhCKqBz@zzka2x7KXKoGyI9gAYoj0QLoBaBJnk6AkHMuUEQmktCwhioZ6Q7M2BeLCeifoJLeFVzQcVYpMBlXkHGbJ/kCK6CeRJBhctH5P0wAFVhfoGMoE0YB7kB/oEFBn97be083qcgu56HNsCBEO4gY9DoFeUQuJfQSngQCoHIKOoD0kiQNs3GIJL8bcSivztEnJ20ngggm/gtzfUBMmGGs9YNe19ZMg3r00GlsU33wx8qYhDEPyTLgbEh7Dn3@85zf0hna1cVpuNfO0yXYc79JAS6yPgD1eHhb86IljHo387skqWkwt8jRNvzgWa9oDZauHRZ/gpgC593izRoVA558eDSoD1e/b4GzSohytMokkOgTSDmtFjpvJQZrY/OoLHtpOV6@QTJ4HlGe5IDmmclfXutvXmNhNHvaAxd05X2PqKxEg0Tefk48DyYxLkgxlkn98It6tBLXROSiaLApfrmsgqOpzk8pO1mYbck8kXAvo2gq345MxWy45O6geFJxx3eYtHiaaSCZY9pFk/OrilI7R0hJeOyNIRXTpiS0d86UgsHUnHwS0xczZm6M6Gw7G1M752JtbO5MoZYdfONYZIaO0Mr52RtTO6dq5Ti6xSiyUIXnpvyU1SdUUDw7hIYhmGu1ZVi3hGAQ330jMChIZeQUL0yCtPSC@x7RlPsk5CRaaCQKFQbP0O2mcJm/LYVPltOvx2yvab4wltFWV304jA5g0DtFJ@hke6g9B5D2ncrUNRoHZpQRF5MAZEC6yUVAHkX/Qe2rtYjfnhescOYkhxq3eIjif6QhyOfJ3AFp8dwaFdwTa20E5s9vZgesWYje1ODpE2lYdbLa2NMbLlt4n1AypY5OgbECEbAstge3/UMs2GMd6ZZPj9JLcQ7kzyFVE23uiuWMgbD0GeWkYl7T/BllqmZ9spIiltMAOcT9EQGXhRoLidOfWZO3T97td/9r/Rv/v1n/yW/vEvfvv//rv/Gd3/Fm//O9gsdGgF8Ms/wds/x9s/xdtf4O1PNyIR@PCh68c/@w28/k//iv7xF39iB/2Tv3T5IytEEIJe65i/@vt4@wd4@z9d/ugK8Fd/ZANiFJf/mdoyrTwA9cv/QNOQGmJZIfuzv6Jplw8MDI8jeXd2HX/Y2PxoI1ix4Y64Hl6G23c8yRt4zHp9LsDrvHHrNx8WgHcDucHjt1XWdQ/MGXspPWppgRf6uMHN8dJMtH8ENGE0M9gDeZt2wehxRjbckPu/Rx/Sbh/CgDfZxZ2ydbiTfyffrnUowvpcDFCHp3E7qMg55ytKoHtLgXyTnsDcDGK3hfRIOVtGHP6W8dtNywbEtZQs2fJwXspJaxkbOj208wkM@F93dVFosRmyd0GTT9FQzg4sbiPBLXXzotgglZc@0GVc74vcjEo8xJEORQLRVvxGxuIL4YL/Jbp1yTnVJl8pvKgweHXAxBxuaqRVQina5foCLHLagfeixRXehrfpdQDu2MPww9Yuy13Aruvraxe14ceiDBldD8GwkSlbZayCuO2g0EZQaCMIaLZxEl0TDYVe0EAaDtSL2zuK7WgbKmo72lq4sOYsywHJgL6gPaDpl5Sx2U@9Rk008raye418AyX3kHLqyb1KdM4J7fK@igA4t@OkXpblbtTsK5jXBbU7JnJ7y2ertN7GtBVno1IQ7lEvubQqOS65q@S2E3wHNffg@8qEQuzfMqHAVyYUi345oZfFinG30L/N3y@rnaWaWGn4NTK74u9tNVDYNP4ZiN5aHSHFBnF6vNDlSTtdns5Uoz07vnUC/szyZLKtD5wYG@eVYSemrFmiPTzwSdegy6GhFbzxgbRdX0V0vkfWUzVDNDd3T8v2/jLVjfv3Ba2nQqvmxxPSZOfrPTgPb5/gst2urFo2xwrN2t9cQ9Q2o9DyfHyUVdl6fATjU5G8awbia1DATT9uCj/WBq6N@J6VaVvRPRqe9Gh5v4yT2Lt2tIYsDD0V3Ql0QyJpGjp0gqhA54vu4yk1pmazBLNIdiijRdqxPF5kYl8baT1R1fDoAoz9An1xjRsJ4nWd0OKneT8tbFDkdKI9gp/3OlEvfnJU@iKEXyJZxg9tI9hihp82XvIYOWvsSO7xzeTsaMv06j@d3vomvfX36ZVkw7Re0kw8cbQHnz8t6bBnjQEA12SEv0yG3zmt5BU5W6SsvPEbQnaEryaxK5oCNH9IaRpA0w54UAL58K/eTHhbEd56i//vF@Ayev5ri48Ys/U56JtRHm0/0kUzyRlOqiB6ALzoRd3zOrmVaOe@Mi2no0N6eH7aRRSXinvHoGLquqiariXkEvEXZB4XCL2Se7JqKGUH7qDJmPjpYejtIso9dkWFn4tdjwPp38C7zHFN5LtEX31dxlHREaWn2R@O8rB@bssUI3t8CdDhGyLD@yde79tiZYPIK@khk3GEwuLb/CMDdy9VMw6Cpuw5EM0ADbpHjgEihy/pc31unwug2N@rdPSo3f7YJVnG4xK@yBDgg/01Qs6/Ttb7nvqseVZZ@ooWYQUb3M4ybv1dYsTNt6/L8Kex6Ms5JaMMq0ipZSlvWSdvlbj8XolvSMVSJm2r5OtE8ktC99UytyFqNrK1Csv@tCbkFeYsryiC4NnEaPu8W2Ka@konoB@WmKa@0ao87lCoq5hE01n4pYqUbV94KRmcRXhO4NmCJyKEPuijLVDLvKFduxzyIiEjXt@wWhyfOwFt0Q0uejfnETegqKUbB3KfV2kKb6YpvEpT2EpzVQO2k9wAooStJJ1SwOJ5rwgUUbLe0M4YhD13eLyntuFSNd7AudfPbtl9KPtp98R9CArZLboP8x5Qyu6u@zBHHKb7sE4cQ/fhBTjWdcv9g/twWS0QwIBX4viE/o4Kx3fBfZj1eJ8p8pXiZbpB9@GqTAHmo/1KOPJsD692nFl/bTWqKop@26j00ygxJjw0zNbdg5/8WPgnoM7ZehD4IUWHDggwdkC2Go2NFsNOB5qNIPkMqmdX83G4HJpyxjfWYygQ7kttDKqglIyJPnLvubeVkU0YhpLBR3gCgag3D3dTRHOvemZfIsdJHSSUFPJ2@oR7QWIPdD0k/A6ANwdxlHX8ZXlto7AL8OvoxMhv0fmKnGVyhCJcDODdQRYy9Xv3O5nCsn5xTptd@psl9HqMAAsxsASxS4mg3dDpYMOhbUoS0zV9W0hIKM72yZtx8HIqJUrvi2hEKzg1841g4u3kDBXDZuX3vpedjXhI2pYKwsA79sGuZat2gehiDFrrug1L1a58QMKGzumSg1NEFNuc4yRwtrrxk7birWZoGddOkmiubTUJkYO4f3PMW3bq63kZ3NX507qvy5hgggONiGAj5ioVW79qP8F@12z7fWlQL5nwIoFdhvXupvS1ef1uK/uCcmWd7OsCxEA/nfPuNI5WKaxZDr2DDcv8PVl7ZeLjB8xsI99OdIX9hbW/ZNuqT/AFvr3sW9i40EowJtueQxyYHYbeZtRri0SZBJdGSxBTcvDYGV9Rus7a@7TaGd9VxBiCbTQ8fnIBG9sFvFl4iI9kwHjBcruW43d1yTzFqm6TL7GuZy7sWQcNV4mtTh3c8AR1T9avrZZogUflsZarlEs30OjG43Hv66kIrLUQd92OU@9OE6y6LSE/HhyFZ12StRN9zbA@3Kuu10vKiAcYAzyZt7HFz6njXkeXbejzF3UX4tmwGxx1cA3X1YDf0kpo6vDYZMsOX@3D8z0HvINkad4Cv/2kt4azRigdOKHz@Eiar8dHXJzz@Oi0Ylg0q2mk3@85388LrddrLL/uvlzNRCwu89XpLDgAMB7ZH4x3BuCcc1fsdSh7gKdoLWOvYo1VS14udsDxIZyiWq2M8IQ5HJ0oSisfQgcuyvCEItiFDUVxO7wdC6Fx4JMsrXTS@WAbOnj8sKlrKjlAkhzKRcx2PAzZXA69ErLH6pQny0DsVMgu/g2K7AVZy3kx8rl18rkC@9v2vGoPIS9546fFXpDM@ISS0OUYyrp9ruBq6YfpJZEIwWSNFvC4o4gj/OQ5yO6O0eRLGUqlX5B7PRAkxvkihL3ApYFfQQ9oUiC7PC9nj26RD9c7J7c6a8LIqcnOODCw07N14JFJh2JgTSX9wNn1DxiLy2RoPNSIJYu0CBT84vCI286EfyPuB8/cu/1cngTDeRHfB88jlqy9BVQ28OsPE17d4LOzM3RjaNqZtCR6YGPmcnl2F@WctZYi85RBXKOme1x7ruWJZui0l03wirA8CsiDh1AdUt@oRPHgCjBasNfWgIGrotFGpte8qyWpKv0zOhwin7OF9IiVSpIFHPbM3hZ2CIOoSKy9us9RMK6fdV0/w8lE6ps91IW2rGH8pSijm5zhupZl@oODzp5QwapsV4HlS3TjJQxdjW92JPzB4/IBFp/L69rCBPDO7Mc3tuZ9HRWUovf3TKMbaxe0dDrdGHFG7TTdS/fTtRt4z7AlX3sQyTNM/kzppnPFzvxUizcmUoht3FxlOmFfNd6d6fLZKHum5yk5cjPy3YZnybPIIpoNZ9MCey2dlqRIPHstXZtiWhGTzGQwvOqKNb3DGaZ8Ub4s1xZMoXnV6l0NpNt2exBX65Reu830rmbiVaKtTlrNZNG8ElvZsjUsD6wxN6/E27HmVDUzrUamfz4vToezYky7kaPZKzHekvSzqTCP6sJZk7qdNPqx@tl8mORG3Xk6a3Zv4j4fc5PN9BJnQvdWOq9nL7o9I9qJDutJPjwZnUv6vH9xpj6VBtn6RPDpg0IxNqHUanEyFSPtYUc5U29rrVYnl6lOh5x5q3cHkfbl2OokjFg4PE6L/UEkWhxbRqKUSV/ErVy62Coo1y3rdt5KVCnrzGrEm@dCUvFNKpYQHueajMm2ZufyRX0aOws1tDP1XCkOqsPT8WlV0cfDXESuNEYRo3dd6Gih0NlVfXJ2U6KMyHn7JlEbhBI5YSYwF1FNG4UbyXLJuJyNM08VsZ0V6hmxE2Mz0es8N7iszIXKpFSrtat6uzmKmxeccltgB1TlWqinM8NCaZTgGuV5MXFarI@z2eJs0glJPS097rbDl9exaaksFttXTPiMH1uXPjlbUZjB@bk5bzUvitdl8xaq9eW5HJHms0wrY0hPuax5WSsxZWPYr0cGaldvxeWsJpxXixGrOEyfTdu3yWJmKErVzlAbNtpKe2zJuQFToObZ4VWzI04L8mLK5yOl1hUzyNcEK57uhevMQJI6Q6ViLnqnpUWvPu70usnKKZsTny66mVa0lte5y4IZKatz6qaRkeRF7UrihtXkWfG2k0/Ll2o0WxX16unZZBYK3chSdRpdcLPrQSEiz4QIW6pkri99V@ehmq/ky2SqWrjSo0K5wmm7F73waQVxwZQk/ime9RnjcWSWG@M33EtNVTFGUYVNFBq@ftw02snLy2nHLF7Xsm1BWSRuL4fD2G2Nup4UTc0IJc4L6SRTHbLGKT8oF2/jslqITDOnSj5ZbC@aCStfGiuJs1Ivd14zco2RcJ3M9@rz@bCXOBerpWGaEhO5Wm3Q6bU6s5u6WZ2zlxFh0PHlT/Plpx7U41a9EDpvZmK9cS3cusipk2qj4Fto1@2Sni0PuXw1MY414uERNZmdJ9J1S5X13OllMnY1lkv5dK7XzHKaKF4/CRfckK835mzCjBtXhesr3fRZjY4W6fQz4fnV5Q3TujXN6JlM3c7asWJ6aAgX3Zl1bsYbakirXLHclVRuKtFJW366qWqD9Ii5aF4vmM50UZhVLcGqD7VoNx4dns7MJ2NxYVxQiZsBrzTLWa00EGIXN/IizkQ5tXGTlS6Fm/MQm272zi7Fwtmkt2iKo9Dg7Gl8JvCCWU3fdE6V2GSm@6RwYlKiGuX2dS/@9MR2xPJNUk4Pm7Vq0Qo1eGZ8Uy9Fn0o3plkQmkU5E5HVcS5zczocZW/nfMOcLcaNWEeR5lUjxOapWfnmsiUMtJ5ZMG@FweK6cKtejkOx68pAilvdITeSuVJLYuNlvebL@arKaac3j7XG4kQAy1C/KupcJj0YVKgKN4pPMvOkaamn5kW5kz1Py@l0KRG60kPxs2H29GzWlVvNVvmsy2uR2042HKt0emyomynne9XIqBevluORUpZqdOZXNa6bS8hcn1eyg/N5RE@WQpkY05rWzq4Gjb5aVrLp9kzKhIWGNo23eUltiotYnLlkfYN@8lxNs5FqjGpaOatZKkzDPvWieBmqzufCdYcfh3np6cb0CTeL/qLSEnlN6ZeealyjNS5l5cGgFcsIDbaSqbPjhTnl9VKVSuaqKpcrzSaFab/eZk09d6YnOrNyN1utih29G9alTiU9k9hJu317ddWsqKPrq9FZLd6pLLr8INqypFqsMrOoJzB5WpNSs9CZ5SRTGtQmT@rpbHzdYiLN01Gp2Z34Bsnbm0lYvq6wpXKmJfHj4lUvbjXLM/3yXJEUZhSq9Bhq2qwuFpaY1vLl6eXNTGotFmk5Yz5xswuGL50Wc9eWL5kvpHOVRp03lErltJRL86Pp5bR0HfeJi/plNyoPn26pqqoqIeO2rsQzbNgMNaO5RVYYnLLj08yocd5IcjrXPGtdXl5wfUUYCfGbSi7WvhTa6fT5xfxc4lvVql69aDaoik@9vr1tMJWGUkpKpWKtoUWLE@Oy3Y7zUy19xbPFyKgzLc0y08vxuD1KnvtuLJEPawtR5GpTpcSIZyA7CUocT6rZctWch54Wg6feJKddt5Jp/TSWzs6l7kScLNh0buJjzMJs2o3JeiLUuJmdSjfCZa93Ucv0w/pEb8SyUeo8KV2qrU62f5mcixdnpVZhbIn1bici@0xWHzSu0k2zKczlUyHWnzTNGwUqn6RHG5ls0lRuc4kLQ/axCSFDCe1LvsqU@tHr8nlXm2Znl615DrocCU6qslFtrrbGiaF6dmFmLtpPF4lEr9k5G0LC4/5tX5Cbvky3I15JSpm6vb5oDfPVcYsZXF1fxqvNM19iETZOnwStf8on541FhWVFKdmbFMezsF4SEqeJi4qgnM/KtaYk9mL10JVyqi6onBrvs2mJm06mKuObRzOJfE/KNMuqkWsKZ3FRq/IMM2vfWpX2deIidMpesfXRlA2Zl1OGlW5UeX5TvrkJdanMxLzQ23VukvedWemb@qAmnCpMuV0rLrR5KR8ym@lyVroYT@d6aS4b4VuhdJpVqoLMgVkSjfUaRnO4yEw6VFualbKZRPw2dAYSZJpKcnoT4UXB1HuzAVO6HJ8ps8F42DJ8oxlT893ezKLJfqtvMkKp1CgXp3kjqp2bA5WKxYTQWdvQ42btaTQvZq1cv9VUItlkq9epnN0wlw3pInmVrd/GxWiVKT6JyXY9xgqlaFtguJo2mljQIgm9IVWas11DUESDj48rT9H8eOzrzidjy6ffxk8vEu3eMMtNBN4XTne0J37WOldYuRwXe2alPZ1cF9pgIaqtSVOlCrdNPXwhn0n1s1blcshV07WFxWSSbeE60rsxOEmVJrWwFT0vir24IOXyt8NB7qz4VGRvpCd2yinG1VW4cMZRccmXsbSuwrSu9Ct1EeLF9E0lcTntLrKjflkSz4qhnHFTi3XrF7ySh2ZUfiqxeqtwWrrtdpQ@I2lqpV5jWeo2Fsq3r2tP3KR7VV00tNmZ0TtPV5XwtVRUtep1i8tdGUw5nilcZQe12@w8EasaSkds9BINdeQ7DWsCn1ZLMSouTsRMq800RTnMxWeLDj8UGe62PRwmzphFzFwwadWcDhK9RbJzOuLat2XttDEfMqej2W01c82NRR/HVQWdurIW1ejpadt3MT9tFntKsygJDD@aD8yzzFg8n3auYmlfQmcbvny31Z@Vqj29nWfinU6Cq4fD7Yj11K3Ozasy1cqVzsLx3NyaSfnhuDxLnOnpWH0@a15FIsPbwaySqMdq0Rk30Yb5jF7oRRnt2oyrs8ZZr5AR89KlZF4uOsKIii3G5WIhkfdFRf6menPLSnnmqd5VrH5Palxch@sxRoieVarT29tcmhnFpUG@qJxCmzjlL2fz@uBm2LmqmGGZ0io3vmJsEVvUb6/KXbXaPr/sd6a9eLxqnLUGyfHiRq/JNZ@@aBY72mmuOlJyi2sQuFgtGR00lXyzLV/namyFsmLt9BRscC5Tkuc9phhlLySVPZ@NTpPXo3ZseDNsZSe1m9lwEKvHo9pYXMSt9lN0LDbjN@ejOiN0bqZ9X@iU0uqL@XX@KmKUylO9ZFU18YJNhEq3w@YoP276RtmLQsfKtlm9E2qXpmNfNgpWQeKylQyVOxeDTHF4emWeXYWSVKMgz8eJwWns1FeFxmQ8MCuJlhJSJkybUVrTiTgcsXw5x7eMWadZKHXL3VCC0X1yfGpdxJ7Ob6q3vKVHVIYy57HulPed5cGCyMk30bqvZensCPoi7PUkfKH2wiFTva7XBSurxYfNcFKMFIyWqrVm2qAVkq9O48OpIF8MqIy46EaUZq3dLc8W025yGOny9UkzXbhW2@GsqvdnpsHFkhehFv9UHRnhiqVXS00ho16NeF6a@mZKJndp1CdUt1dOd9uFp7E0aUUq6Uh6ft1lI@PbyYBTF9f5m9Cg2kn3pWmtHVnUpuFM95RTayNZHxkhhm201PwwMWueiRfU@SIvzvuJq0y1FWleDJLDsNIb1qvsfFiRJeH21hxzxZte6YrrFqOtzFVyeCaZaTHeTErnA2ZW7lRuY9muGGEpX784YkLZkhA@z1/7rHNBiT7JC65sLZKSOi835U69N0nrpe6gOS5nzpgMF5qcziqj8FmNCY/5zCiRuzBuDIUS89H0rFm5jJn927TVimjV0CSh31bl3nWoW@3zwoiNJUAHX3Y7t/NmupaZlm7KZ3UzrfYWos@YXqinxUIho1JnUrv8ZD7xmjROR5qV0s3V01Xa6DWiHcsscrMnkZnP1cp5VhDmN@miOSy3zutqMc6OupnL@FW/W1KbWlUOX1BCMj68jjNqXTgfs2Kkmo4UnlqnwlNxEqtpQ9USGvlbzirXQNkVo82KfjMdLbJ9VpqFI/lrs9Lr6rdQWwcLKjQ@q910a9JAnU1r51brIjyqc8PWVBnGVF73RfLJSoXnemHshEWvNXWkKRc967penlwYDNNfxMaifipeyFQppPfSxVrsPMSfnt7kkk1u9FQSQ4nLyDg9DVVqlz41Kuq5Ym@ksNlhbSBeydBlaMeqg3O2Xpabvdtx9jo5r1OLm46UVM/bU@0iO5zmhpNBozkLQ/eq0SqZZr12bXWLk1DnPK50Kv1uI1fIXglZnjfjFTWbrwz1caszmp5FotSgEL4eXMbP5V5sGC@K85uLsZ6sni@K2f5ZxHejniesG95SnirK4KncsazOU1xu1a/OmXYmLqjs0zxuXffbjEmdJUb504gYXxT7XLypjibjcbdSU7XivHp1CWyOh8KN0w6T1ttXVavVPROF67MmWPrnmlisX5/r9dPrs@64q1JKGMQ3yxgXpyWzcJ0b3nLTYm3ekTnfsHIxrUTjUSnZ8U2io3J/nItG2/HReXlSyOlGbHYJWr9XnVdLYq18SXGjy5v80HcucVzCuFy0JpFaWryOdS6n0jQSzaVnaj@RaLKzq/NT4SrR0YvTUfOc610x09vk0BzxTb6WFjSpQmWe9PA8N7PybDR/ETu7vhIHsWk3Pw4V09N6uxizkmWp3Y48TWvToVgucFJjNpmGqoXKlaVGorPW1e3wAkohSgm92VU@Ll5GxC4rL26zRkHrqE0@zTLnTGjabF35tJ76VBZ9w2qoENZjeXZW5aFnfJsZn3djneZAaZ9mzpJ9qhsR8r6GGSvexp6uny5l43rgi49A5SSk2uTqEkySjtVsRGZXUvKGW7SyiTbfKSy4/AWTjpydjZPFUOi8lCzdUGY9OgJpeZqGrs9zSuiq2mpExr5cOTfr9uu3zVp2epm4veFG1XZ9co6dsTDDTqXKoNaclwuzpizG8sNaXspQvuLV1KwkdamWa@UNptqVCpHB8Oy0cCqOL4TxLK/62F6xOZ88jUdi4vxS4UVDLdSsfloI3ySG4ZlQ1NNPFy1qfsbnz7lsopUwhrJwPig3zYE5aeuSnI48RWc@qzaoyhfRXK1xrQ6a/XLZELKXobgp5ob1Uey2OZh1JmK@e05JVnIiKLPTcsxSM/OCfN28vDrv1tm5UE2clwvGjO0whac6O7GYZqJebfQ6ZUMuDaDh9N00NS2hgEqx@toVxev9IjttpS@6iZ6ZPWUTpfNZpSmXfexVvjbIhcyJ4WP6o0oot9Dy52FpGu/Vri5GrJGddPu@i2qcuR1ktGmZilrdcJs3h8maxN3ctBg9X1uY5mWi2fFdXCmMWAvdxjNnC67RCevdcf8mcTM6nTzd3Fw@dVr1MyjOa58Yq18@Ub2rizMzLiUFrtvMZEtpbaKz58aoJkVGJe2mGbqRfDezXHH6FLpgC4NihyuX@4tFRjg32moiN@pcZvn5oJloUeF8he3ehkX9vJl7uin0xwMhW5oJ4WvtzPRdR8qz8amRiMe4SHLCm@HWaNTyJdKK7IuH@/N@KJOfxHJM16i1qXzFl21rGtSC2m2MLzNmpFtWLLMZb9TzyVq2kD0rXeSvpVKyXuSvr303V8VsPt2InV/0h5GLG87MMJnL/qAeogal7LDLWFZiLNflgpk/NXKz/u3wajTuTOOTknmzUC/4sdwbcRKvD9slNR5LX7WeohU2nL9k8rcLRQ3Fo7Mk1RWk7jmj1IbX7YScP2NulD50oHMg/8Pry7EhSIbZT7Yh55cLNZ5tVnot40zpV4FCpTPWBWmUlId9MXxL1Zh6ohBvKxeSULmpjeI3Hfm6cR6OS@MZ9F9vcosLKcdAqTdv6v0xex3Lg@kaiTwV2/3R1aTcMmvRXKtRqkao1lMtJ3HFfKnUurW6XLnC9goTqxlPnOU5YZQZlvPzTCdTnBaEZvvMN/CFGl1hUmillXyry5uz@S2bZI20NKBig9hlRspx1jTakoxI9rxfCfNKUZtVzhP6qFY9D2XO81eSNjTYzFV6ecVa8@RIjs57Ujp92ireZHtU@iqbG4RakinUVN@0SMAyBYX//U8@KkQ0DJWAURNN7uLnnUzROebi6J2DJ8jJE7i9fevcCVzss3mQgOTsrwZaIB2/q4k7hA/tRMjcZhA//YFTi0cv5xYD3PI4AfLAczzoA/K5D2lrItRlYOQVGR9k9T0CyIwnmUHBeTCyPfln5iH8gAb/EiWwieyo8xDeeL9IG@EInvOBx4ayD0cbU54ebpMaJBCKjFcl4Kff9TM8VeFbiEimgPOVgnfXtD57tBUfiDN1lZw04goEXSSqcyoGYtpGYZcm@q/OZqDIgSzLibV3PmbGM1yCjSXJ@R606rf8o7vkg/9ASLlo0ZJ5dWSOjWl32NP6E4lWaH3QmQnzxRNNRyM0HnMU@tY@UpSLpRhynnMc7gk6SY6A3l@e6EmOsMcTvcjpjHiAqJumV@dZHX2gvcThx9uh6@iVlNIHo6UU2od8jO5iDyk1xR6N7tSHI9Xn81q@lOXjfB70@JbzHuljZyXinfVAdu0zB/Tlcms9fuoD1/5qEl3VVKGvuU2afOR9c88JOblsWYFGvL5ZnyaiYGnGpo@E8sSPtiriay@cJeZfxJS1JZw110WculudSqBoIL94@2Ycixy9DsccfvMNHqFx5Kyd2MzAZ0ofdxRZOKS@IfzEKXDcTn946BwKI9Aot998Q/xk29OmhZZNDwYfLUMFTZ87kWUb5HGZl@MNlCcenFv1@r8GcgnVAZl8xA@zGQBmg9js3QKnATWZGvXaVKG7JKqreVA8x8d7hKec0B@WYcsTfxAe5Yacu/No0TI5pQcex7QDSs7AoL3OiRPE907GTW9kKcGJ2w76ZjAe6WT@OWjT63AEvzr7qPOysYoZNMf4NXoPzSEz5CXRWALoeMaT3ya8JW4WzbIscOEb2XyF@UF8VfLpICBY4PFT2qAbcfMB4utqJM439meNPbSl2QsrbTKcuCQbXqeogXF42rpbdx/SZB3cEXiRKdGjjdABhGJe3wgeQfCIt/pvBPcR99j8/4q72rU2cmT9O30VokmCHfxJkt05GEgMGPAevtY2yfAQhhi7gZ7Ybq/bBrwJP875cW7gXMC5uL2Q2XqrJHW3P4CZPc@zk2dwd0sqlUqlUqkkVc1LHlAygh3PSfYpWe5Ezk4PKF12@udkGOKUJ7HrxTC4GDb9TkocesAVyIMI7JRaXjaEtSygpGOkP5LllXaNohakd4TZEuxF45PZSjKApVN68OA94hZOhTP6lPBFrE6hifqunqxMH44kEl9wTSR2UX/6TQK@iiFA449EqZpON5VLb9uGJvgnR9PONXqbiPVW/fjxGGaaEZP8Vzw33Cc9hHO4sRYKtSI4Eos16lcp9HddaHYZ7TomLt3MGYmoHWZQrkQiRMZWNK6v/F6b6iDAC/HPOPKUVh@iL2fhuVq10iOiowyLp@m4MsU9OBHFIzKjLqPH1vOp2gTfU8kmzciXkbCAn7BmaYqcoc2dTebeoNyWmhN81krwjB6lv7exz2vNIuHHg5ppUxJB2yLVcEMjOAO9pvRrXCYIsJdLq/IdkWP9JDB/DjDxp3dBAIZrhANmNiPGzZzo93JyJ5XkfGHlXYaPmEuWh4hMRlg9h07/D4MLhNNT9gjB9JIiSc0gzVR2227Qa2NyyE00TyT97MadyaXmpQ9LwFFN8xNz3QeaJVdVQVnHTSX18LQc@mOU@R51X0LfCVPzZYXpdMOJz2HBhzmEfpLJkk1YOVcJigMFlgxPTEnshHD2pBQdrb8wX8yxSxnbczUwYFVKpgNnAWgSSFGOl8ponWsjEp3a@@LF0Cg3mUgLQwxb4QpS2UtOXJxjObfDk3f8q3UdxRSJp@AmOzTMgcHMvzK6LanBplyudYFuFiKDnjSmr4OgnTIKk1YYGILx0EGZMuLOyqpVol5G1VN1WulV19rLh5l3S/RlQX/ieYU@QPnUvAkk3lzzsClh2MT0Gz/kEMucjtmIqjK3D3BYUaSPWp38jtxWBXoxs5CR@PBJxp4rtZznmTghHtytZg8HQ9EdsrRec/HddgTybNBCO/JvyX3wMMPKID48tXfL7/Gli1/yc9CJbaebU5DpksVmbc1FNZbhH35bXMiPwkH@0u/lvd4tKdWXY2dReT0JBriqRsOr7E84KFyu7X7S0oTPZfMhRGIT6inUlut5dynkIc0ZXkTdtCM@6fjQYtGBB2I@N97xbtuk9YvHln4Q3vPfMS0WCrlRfxhwiq6IfdepH/6PyJ9qgW8R6RWDRmeN4UR5UrhfIF/HclYyWxQFqQjvyukYiDOUZIHrfnFd9B8Q1edJz86dMOc1WzdAArz3Q5ZT1F3MyQ9OaLoevtZAClxeoceOeJno89lRVMHaSTjmd2o@3ot4kC98xBV8r9cpDh8IRkonCPpgchwFRfk1IoAQ/kW9sV2p1XI6jpKcWMcpdznHjCuC7LCO4zLYY7w4rQ53gdIpL9BYwJb61iPgLH@ZRqhWkwlD4Q7kFFrBH6G0IFvkt6lm2Pxpyc4k4etO@i0ELQvaq0ef9CjQLiqWihXLmmImc4wUL56kRrPVgiOIA68bEMZbXqdDSAstXkTkwCMoYupftvWHZ6jz3CIv6dmp9GwiPSfpglSUK9e6GUSZVuOZ3MXvUb4H5UbZMlN1rStqdPWQvUvlgkEM79JjecMcLdL8KPOG7UrhSpuwlkjIxlJ@mdH7krKQKGMZ3KafSbrm7xXd8xbLRN6Pyfrx6@gO8tgHg76yOMGluZ7f@SDmR5vCElbBrZIUR38z28mg1AYRLU6yJCaIiXnYbqxHUJaLRuLwmHE31j66OW2S@pCaREPCAE4NrBljJEYlrnOZCXfPMwnVw8kLMRAME4ymzMjdMIXHuvA4Bha5Fky1jvEUmhzg1LTJIb6OY90/8McM9iRyJt/i7MQXgvm9NF5uWiQJxEJ3wZ1NpqQ0GQ5GnnzUjXpkFonqHk9CnC0kDgOsQFs3kBS2Tk/ug1wFo157wcqJuKAwkmKK7jZFUzrKUDTsO68Lkfjg/JZ/4@w2u6QVdrx7VYZO3WSf/E7iss3QC4chjQGPGjhQ4ajf7/jar5u64@scOiLQyntcRoggxpSGnFPFBVHJn8GTvhxDhXLqCJDvcM8wSghH14iwDkswgoWTaL3yCeQw55R7Y/ZMzG7QVuTKi6dG8OMKAdyhZV8MCek5GT1seYCWlnPMxSJp6pWM796QVCBqeMA@D@FqddVx/jryW9@2dtVKofDnYuFtMUYyY6ou5N6@U9WYimQSVgrFQuF98Z3jbAX9sVxtTLXSgPUuC4AZtY@J/hPxpneLYN5OmWYMzhiS6h96g1uvnXOcmtdmG/DliCkCVh6BXD3j5xVfSLeCv3tSd7thRtGy6wbiBb@Yn8V3bYsda2Qc3CHqe4OuP5SbRsGt3wYBzb2pq6DTCe7YEI0rS0IPFOp6QyLKm7RKosR@aTUurLuwu1iiBqI7sAO/y@CW/UhrMpCe6sP9Pl8AcuBEERDilfXaE5hQfa1O0@@CnWYgAC9LEQUMAtS09qjlPYqDw0j8ThyUblg7aI3gmbdpeiZP0i/gsULD3Rv4JH0jAnOvcLEY7tTBjb1qXdWPdhqfy7WKoufj2tGn6nZlW22eqsZeRW0dHZ9yzDC1d7RP0qWuyofb9PWwUatunjSO6INbrlNJlxOc8uGpqvx8XKvU6@qopqoHx/tVgkbga@XDRrVSz6jq4db@CU3WuxlFENThUUPtVw@qDcrWOMpwraaYE5VTRzvqoFLb2qPX8mZ1v9o45Rp3qo1DVLZDtZXVcbnWqG6d7Jdr6vikdnxUryg0zNmu1rf2y9WDynaO6qc6VeVT5bCh6nvl/f2Jhh59PqzUgHyilZsVwrK8uV/hmrid29VaZauBBkVPW0Q8QnA/o@rHla0qHio/V6g55dppRgOtV/56QpkoUW2XD8q71Dgn9QRVqF@2TmqVAyBNlKifbNYb1cZJo6J2j462mdb1Su1TdatSLyln/6jOBDupVzIKsV@5aoJB1KJ0et48qVeZbtXDBs0ZJ8eN6tFhmjr5MxGGsCxT0W0m8NGhtJaIdFQ7BVTQgTsgoz7vVeh7DTRlapVBhTpRbasRz0YVEhEb8Waqw8rufnW3crhVQfIRwHyu1itp6rBqHRkIJur9XKZKT7jV6CfCSx6JWR3DuRnuTlXdUeXtT1VgrnMTB9SrmluYbFt7muY0lvPOzC23Rzfwpnf5tCnkcSfxW0fbFdL4JDqMG30/oUnnp@TmXSKNJhqbSK96F5Tnqou2dzm6vvB7VwGW5raY7GB3w@sM4imlEa/3i/NIVHG9Uc4FFhcvLj6VL2idW7@4SGeeUzKBxlMltBfWx3KldRs7QbPNy/yEbSlOqI3X2td7Rhwvx20tr63xIa3y@bani@HyIgAbM5EOSkDA2pCMfKux2VOxKnmLOWkr4ogZk8Yis70ZhPSn9yN6kbkh9oGEs5xbyOexhmU0EPlEWfypEg4KoiOD8DkA/4qrzIWe9@06VYhXhyW/NlClTRnOO6Rl4HUq/UTxS@96onh2sjwji7umrKwYd/DGTTsYM@A3TTKl@yU34JalxLTHP2mDDVdESmFaquKLrPr0Seq1FId/UbEVpkvWlTiHAzko/1z9jMVcYeVdaeL7nv0uYwu3zhHbhua7My53zj9755KBBpiP5ReRxB/Llmo@HytDWhnrkzYzfNXfINOd36Y5FVP1jcfTOjzki7vgeHmajAf@fRx7EsO7tfLB5snODklOYPvup/d//lPJ0R73B8OfM/J7inoQWJOpS1r0nU9qGifFRskW6T07U8FyYtF90HvIiFCTptP4Y5NUWus5U3QEia8hZiA0N0SEgR6CbLgIEjBwFe7newuO4deZI1MzQCrR1DRa023es4bfJFWJeaAlXjI7Y@61e/wBbDv8zRC3DdIMpFnM6/aHY@JcWlyw3HN3jMMBXtvwtWJkybmGj/tNcwZJCAOZyV4YcAef3zRvx3qR9Fp0NMYrdzuXJCQWJrEwQVo45BJVcRyEZgTLR5@@/Kz5jR5PdXAgJCHUQ3lYJzLu2JJZE7xHbM56YGjI5xvr1EWvX9ua1hQMqWmNlNj/k6Fj4qOBUZEDDWoCsDl5ZOlsU9gI/XEprb4Lp8KrN@CUNMfqd@LcWc3RUErGJbp@NxFklMCKAsrwpztbh2OynJoslpwJMv1L9GD4/0aazIC/RgtOgh5Ri@Ww3xt5z6QkQxVa0eqVieLfmRNjsWNqETXjn04jMA/xjrmxDdPH8O5lY4lIoHtnbD6cSkix1AwCgMlh14iPXzjw5UF806SV00ceuy9kp3/Qa3X7KROQy0wVU3DPM6xzZcwRObykZQu/oGLV7SO@ykf288gyAwsukmKXY/UqdAXGcpFlDhqdf8NGDzvKmTVBhqIZ4RE7FfTQMoP/Xp8wimaZtkl9IFV0frAvux2CmEIJgW92QIwA4bNP8QZrslGdG0B0Zrvh6YWt/ErP4ohySSKQ52XVYPccYfOK18yYirQvDTjtQJWA86qtYzZdesM7TBcdgc4@RCJoKvWK3ZigEm2LtGqEEb7pHFGdJ9k7iz2bKcGvFvuT3rceoix7YuIyOXKJCFBxF6w5ddDkYFCd57XbjSpfBlk3kvVXe@xXpSX7lTDN8cqdasFK/1UYUYQ0zjtolzQPRVRqtr7ho2t41L/L@vf0w3VldctNTCNaM3DEullK/8PcBQF4ZeIMrHK/9KwRaVUmsvVXRn3Bk4xd@3SKJ21nXqdGEXL0BQdmtRoElKE34ZDm9Ghj/BJudXD4dJU0p7u73GVz1G32rppdvzPmU6e/Bje9fNgbhf1cf@y4rpu0BsIROFykEO5DT332e@3gLlSbNBxgSKofntSPk4a/mOVrSyxfSv2F6lCbXLMzBf4KPpPC4GpIXeOV1FgHOB9E5h62E2pLC5u1xvgAx1QDZiCqt2s1493DE7Xr9bwB6YPHfOZS7fstr0fig5QpPoUZ3oikQfYd1F7Xtasd6C5s2Skpz2ejjrXtOboCDS0D1krRUCSEBzqsImzzY2L1mE0wN93gqF1tY1S6CfraGxCMplA2xcR5NepkHMRu/Fxt7GExLgtzts3QtGZsfbAliurUFWMtNWbQ7A3HRBRn0nhDaD9lu8kpdgZEEJ355ORFXRdR2tsw@3VCaiqi02spwDMIDVXPv0WwODbDPaeP@JytNptFdCtp/4oZCV9nREei95yo9zKIGZrLqPf/oRoeeFcdd5otWmGp@gjF374lPXAzCIfIelBWqrBSLBazxbcw0Z7UyzkeCPjfRBBznOrB8VGtQYTULvINY9g5E8TnoF1yGovIkUXoLmr9Vwhkk58k5spXJh5UcOPH1y3JjoW76lLft5ow91ILw6Q6zCZZmOSDAQcOgzcoYqHEcKRa4fQAIfpYSKKmGPQMhy7TwcdkarF4sjc/LvAVuHWIrzrYD/3KhfkbCQDvnr9RqQGvDNra7T31SdfrWuz9oZndm5LBmYx5ZgkmtlRijqXMErQkol46Dqft4YxEiOgB3fC2NSDZ0rwllsMRFuMSi3iGZVPatqZ56Xd8GgOEV@smwIQj4sp0BJsg4hHRHO5xG2sHExLjMiNaAY2udtC1WQUrx7HO4PT3fjhuBWrxmpbZWGmFfc9rc6SEUV9CASA9R6O8QzOHuIlbjWIEOIsFPjc5IGGDkCwk@0Yd@I6Fr79L6XPHtIa4yrgXbNxgWS@AqEX1IQ9SRGxLzVhhZxT2edPc7U1iCJRNgxBzHP0RiH4Gm1KEFfU3MwQ/Mbtk4I6qw/096QcQBTkYUdhPJgCW7Op6yQQDHm3Xj1MZhEnXLQITLgYNMuInS54TNrDkC9qLc6dwmpaSNlLjxmlLzB0fITTFNhCo6wB/kTlnKCZ7hB7vEU45LryHS16CN5mzOJ2TctkAIrGcKzNgZmfCfDsbZlbD1JuV1d4tO2xDKWYLaYV4gw5IPoIQUfN3AyN62a1cJ5ANJtv6605wibhNJCmoNvyMM1HHxj/zCixB6HiqOBFMxptaM03SqOu7TUZ3UWs0PrwNtWYsFhtfetJROmFdxhL7LFM8d/Fw4kf80SOKH91E8CpoHRPRq4CefCXZDbCuBqm/uKsqGpk4iRPPr2tOFukmihQnimjkkkUuE0VWnMhT6UTvogREP36TLTN6CZ9K4h5Q67aDCk63eS@rmwI7oGMzDUJGJjzirZxrBkHGs5ayPu2Q/dyJXDQntu2lDvPKR/D4xLf70uWQV4VkvIN7c3SPxQDnSqSP2Q14L6UblNZk4Bfr/jltkNHtWuMivZiksg2WBCfR7AHuaqXitaRX1WK/KbuGyBViYotXfcY0wC69S//eqJSuIBtHVjLBra4WhUR4dr18RktZ6RYjBwtONDPzW0zAUQ86Ir/5yJhMA6lUYlwZyW1hyuOU7CZQ@C7guCZH/H@GpNfJV8woMdFQh8KHMKZayfPuaXnGe8wMgucfa7HWH8WnsZUeGvmzqOZzM2skWzE39@RUMitPbFaxVHgssyG2pdPczPNnGyYdbAiQd5I9Rrp9GIk16cwUvBQKyVhL8Yfs7DRo@SKhkmSLCV0pm5khgJNdbpDLTLTKibky1y2cnEacxMyZYJJU7A1h2tUrCWQngNJOohToP6/DcdwxPrDn5itKPt3t8zjCwjL9/hhb2Mym3x9jC8kc6/bH2cLEMrSk5fKTfJHoCSEBDiXqFQPblOIyyCTcx3PdT@RihMbncV/mXic1A9uYVNW2TmdKVbIk0qFLknXwz710zKJ2NJpgRyLeme2N86i1NMe1vnlt65FZt94ukTbc5JQgvTkZiACNNjVwH52nETLbFiCJLUYwvWbuytlN9mi/JAsWXoMiatf1TfJ2bwKsmVUK6WmF0njvj5Bfm4l8djqKQrTEWp2OD29Pl2msceApGLSR23Vm7Pg6T2C1HMMq2bpYDyVJPAdS9lmQss@AlI9B0gP7Lc2X/Lg4QJw67ykQX75Mw@CfX2ghpWGQpG37MGJjHXzXHD8Fc4GUrUU@U9eUU2W2QKQnPwXjwyQMjgt6Y3fj9MebJqxuf/cGwWRUjrmUTfLKDIwsVovTaGWAFkttXu/qfEZV4rVt7tvljW9XAotP97T4MdaFcZT4xm4CLSa96ltg0fgvzqFfJtatyfEgiCfMMKQtO79zOORACLEwyVUxWyAmyJLrUJ2QJMTjqZPCj1erk96PEfB0brH0ky35KAafmNGpSE0TiZXgOLOEi4STma2MfJu1PHuy/sWZ9feDPuk4VzMR4Pxd2PHFKDUh0iPVdGJp/ay5bOZ8Nt2uuN42EZvk@YP89VTTV6jpuJhOg7rn3enZ/zHIui2mB/6AJn9meGQOkq9mIomN9qY2bqneqHvpDZznDHUpkcOPrJHmc67jLC6qcouWzNozPqxiLQ7f5@kqoQaDEUI16mO/JpTDnRjcsJF5wsCTedvBXY9z51xUwTbartfsaVf5esK8HmD/wubNIHwnLndxDX6vRYQOvZj586vEpG57OgUnkh8ha2l234OrUafGIhPVpNESXTM1Tq5p5escBcdqNZxrdVJRMbyDzdA3oplrfYkU8/RsE9hztKfHFCJi4nlV6gXvBOjHeXR1PjFHfUtK2zXPIOUsdctauZ@hbo2fq279Gyg52aFO7FlrD3qCXX1SqE0u8p3f8nkbmLE7w3XLp8bOTsLhyeXYrAq63uB9oVCAE5zLZsi7FglvONgl9oN8MnceNvF8/@4vg0@XeRTFpgUiE6yazUwvDDokasJcMLiWaBTAgbIiN7YmwCfYmhjRfBML9wB7Tg@3cn4NJad44GkrPsbp28PtnxrMfAwSxPNW1Vc0EO37qq5GPTGi3zVlyaChmPNmVBpq6K1rjskRefDhCh517JE0BsbrZn1rARsf6xvfnRe8By7XBTlcfPp7dA3R3fM6nSCjPgeDTnvBlduhyQI7O/ECBcmCo4QyeEIOX5xR3q3fiYVwRhbgFnS8XCe4ZnDYAdfXFvku08DrYycthXms5l1X7vsp9@wXlxiTmryMZi4r9xzXe65dmqJc3kJ/GqwEzCC0n5W72@ynWkynycw0B@q7VNETYfS2mFF1OR0Me8oWNRmHOVKJLGnxCyM0ezo3iDob3dyvgd9LUdOR7OC6HF/95u7llszJbonrfrkvXoGGBYGhcUKInueVeCjB6dQf/w/WbVgOcLmRbbz2SmzM31i8HcYYj5GlbodXVzS8xBK/YVyNGXAsKrNFPqUA0uiOHXh/Q6yC1NJVuCQBVnDUpj7utRKInK2cZ9TSaHj10xJB@Jfa6JgRqIcf0RPHJv4zS8N6Z8RxvCN5xmY4HKCYljsocIECjvOqtf63u1S5XFYv@8vLqlzepIdsVpU3y2obHzY31Ta9b@L99frK@/clOTm3nf5OHzfNxwe1STB4ClqmhcA2vVLaOlZUWEqhi1/m119mSi8v1tc2SmH@rLx5ns9f09M//ut//vHf/5sv65f/w8smv5z9YjPlcrn8y9b3l68fSng/2z5fenl59rJ/vnRdApf9Ew)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
140 [Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
142 [BitChanger](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
149 [CSL](https://github.com/jammy-dodgers/CSL)
151 [Black](http://nethack4.org/mirrors/blak.tar.gz)</sup>

### Explanation

ChuckScript is a language that is like Golunar for JavaScript instead of brainfuck. ChuckScript finds the first string of characters that match the regex `\[0\]\{\d+\}` and then converts the number matching the `\d+` to an ascii string. This string is then executed inside a javascript `eval()`.

The string I converted to ChuckScript was

```
console.log(152)
```

which gives

```
[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
```

This string was placed at the end of the first line of TRANSCRIPT code.

I have included a ChuckScript to JavaScript converter written in python in the test driver.

Answer (score 7):

## 160. [TinCan](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TinCan), 7623 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\  
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`============================================================                                                x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L  
#R+.----._>]|  
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 999; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈ +-------+ 
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/| 
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/| 
♈|       |
♈+-------+---  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#- 49, A9,-1                           #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#                                     _
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<110

>{-<<mxf  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --9ss
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"5""6027""ing-?" ye h m 3 ;p se do{--}gibe
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"--}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                 @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1bb/NKkiD4fDj7D/aFn@w6kqwLSd1lW/4@XS3JsiTravlyfCiKkihRpExSVx8fdO8uavoy2J2prmnUdM90VfXMYhvYeWjM7gIz6AYW2Hkd9I84/dhYbP2D2ogkdbNlf9@p3gGWtshkZmRkZGRkZOSVbV7v//a3B3jRZVVe9GTVoA1RN@iOJk1FzUsnFvQnXtKDPj9FIVRc601GomLox9QBzdG0pAhSB95pQx2KirQUNfD30fRYU3saP6KNPm/Qoi7wY1Gn1Ykxnhi02t0fzU/T6ZE6kDwYcyQpPQAzRG2siQYJD9B0XZH5UbvDvwgJvkhwrEG4TqdE@bvRdwYtqKMRr3R0gAzRdKqUSBfiLzCEafpS1XQR8QiirqvoGaHpeVoUXoBGAZTXJLUQL56/COJY@hxI58eyOKf5tm5ovGBIqoJBHF0t1qvllzF8dKOWybz09dMXHlWhMxNhuBNEyqCsqZ2JgPwx@iIEI0@7kizqlAB5P6PHVkl60UEf0JrId0wwqqtqNEahR0OZlmhhPKbbMt/3CrQsAWyGjdAiFgG9hHC5r9Pz8YjWpRFg0dWRuE2LTiui2KH1sShIXUkgFNDi3BAVHXKse2kJaJ9Jskx3RBkibMgS3ICMnuhbXiYRXqqjUjRcwvhFJtZvhyLAKOKKEeIYSgIZoWLBAVdW/Jhp/HgMRAIzq0C4IY1A/iTDrtMir0so4RBFF5UO4eF4LfsqzSvbuaSnEk/zQO9EI7h1UcMC9RK8dF/UREDJr6XPMdMkA1iALI7TZZHX6Jomis7derCTJCSmYgoGZsRLivD01J4uZexQlGYMLz82qAPNX7vKUzztjdGHDyfwi9lsJ1S6mKKfDu/QbYo9FPdYc/BOOvY9rTN3dyL85lyb6WnPFGClgCsyzahjg@E9YyDQYwCBDI9OdHmmPu9Y3kqYPn1RFlsCZkJ1oDTonEI33CRnwkTTsGpvmMoPIdOyqvSAn5BZbaIgPxQ6xEIRCCrUTDctToFrIPKkjNQZ4XCtL0Gh6VgkW5XJVFCEoaCiQPYsjq7S1VV5QuAgpm6gAAJXICpizHXpBt3lJRmjQDiiMqnWRH0iGxhnonSw5EEBiR0vvSJDUDsINFKnkBwPSIkH1KfRVi0kRAEwFIRKsopBP/zzP@/0eoAnLgiq1rHEtUF3VIGoUp4QC/qJRoFVFV4mZAGcG1M3o0MCU16WOryBySsLKwlCBEl1pk7kDq1CgtpMgqrV56dQHbtdUTBEU8hN7eumR/zQ1B2SKbmQ8RHfhoIlCZC0SbY99KcklJIgUgdEZjyjidGN0J5xmrbrzDeOj8eOjx/uRCDO6XUeHTJM7wQEzntEvODN/p7kNOI72lE3eF2VOtR4YfRVxUd7BNomxNSxqDjsOzjsbrvWtju9qNMczhMpJni7ktJx2E9BFs8gYbvzRIgJt9Lx/cmL6NtJApoZosHqKjoEp40ClUMqxZQZ8ZLiHS/ohsdybYWp@gOyHIO9W97ImJd@U9PjgLQ@KJcqCgjoIa8ui@LYwXo5J6oJhNubbwzYl9MXOKwMH0v3LvuB3bWddYIBcrqTUaysNUlFtSWP@9jAAFMUfQzqW0PZFXiQHh21uAEmgJtuE7kmqh80C9GJM9GuiXQbFOlKjkiVNKscxvegorQwbKrQCm63RoudrQoNygDqtKG/0sqyOoOECW3YhoEKUTBxvgdFBJHNDMXNDJkpEp/drA0VUCyIrS3SEU9bgsqA1Q50uyX7W3kEcL/PhAFsZmXZ0kEjfgFYBLNN3FQcWupCnRqBmtAWtCCi7gElJJoNCyYyIfVQB@MHzSDW4wsGd@vaq6pmaEzccwPKesm8W6Mw89uVChUO3RVntMwrvQnfQ/tLgSi8IIhjw1JYkBPdAJX0st0hnh6rEfXqferw08u0SWNiNa9baaCyN0vPahJ51DKWBeaRQanSvGVD0h1JA/UkL16mDgDTF4nbvkWQHQK@tb1BwsoSACET56IwMUC7gSDP@pLQB9lF6hRTP5qN0cvkwWs7ddDwnu46aSSGO/vaR3mZtReS8SYKD5boazzQyCKqsx0PUvjbHu9j5vXRHsTqmkRoELZ8vQzvBdn7DM6Rqqh7kAIj12gRZDfELAewyKpoDUIDtjK/SGVdm4jrIoIyA@0BNR/kr28YY/0Y2gvJ6E/aXpAUpqYtckZJQWFhDG0hGarpbstqG9SzDvWTWaXACJO2NH@RIeK3LsOBTk3BEOvqdAxa8McJSJ3D3tVBcRL/JAJvBdmIAicozLsNAAmQFxjl6OpEJWdAqVQXiuCweUlV8kKls7lpG1ZcmxMcGGvNl6Q6Qi1EN4mBgBZfQgPN1QVtZel@ovr5vU3eug0g9p3d7h2okuJ4sn/48MF@bD8DDf/hw0dwnaLrI7pc4PpIXB7iQjgvukgMN3Fh6C2JgX739ufbFea58x6LbY6t01IaO/jb42P/vZu/5aynD59OUHWg2QDagw/AY3fGYuh0Om1nM8iot93dzX0StXNV0KSxxYQ8P@XNd4sLfsIGaTRWNTRkT7CxfZ8no5gGrSEYr0Lfodnvbtm7@7unu47r7tnuxtjOEz7WhkxBeo6Rt6epE2g2nbeBYw9373Te@qGxbMfsrP3I4Yh4ZEiIdzp/EnG6eJPbDrsIWttxd2cHplr8uRX6GsE3d/uczjWrgA5soME2dNi9TxFIv@28d7rsENdpd0NXI2a3A2cEZIJOMo2SSRiUAQFMVgs7Xb3RENQjLegy2hQezTQr4JU5Mj075LE2nY7pHGlZFWgvgQRoLjvrLo6iKh5lQgxhYqWq2wmRzhhCED9sPFAxSjswiLgrzcHSh4q7WFk02ACjUZOE7p4qi94msTFsNEg@jfXVu9esKZvtglfQN4UIBgw4xzIvQM3cRXdno@8AIQgqw@wPcZ68QvzS5iHdk8/lEVoGgVeQfx2JmN8TSe8je8FEwj6B1gWuou0NjbtIuJajBWi0e8BpcS4ZpjEOglDFKFledzjR/Iub5hNabdjkI1Grrjtpj1UBOi4iNP0YavYC6bQylTRVQSZ704AaJPYEy@AF8n3sBTGKx3O@1Nv83YccOPbKm9vi7TbWl8wVdIFmFFVWeyp9BAAoml6vJdhQOWr9iUiJQl@lbXfQhPjOaKYjThkUSBvo6j7YQh6wN0SNtLbraNbgDWWoE2i2O6IsjSQjR0YxZAXbpo3eXYUmoQA2CMqSaFCWQblprnBAY6NKlJ4Jn56jxtEpkTzpYimVfijHa9mYjZnoGiNLbchhR3wYgWUhi7qNpg/oigixrQjLoVxRVSNGKimOnby@DhBoBV9IPRRyiUq80jKTIfF0aTSReUzMhK@Sd5PA3PbAS1dTR2srSrd4e@hHboo7A2jYtbBCAxg6sYbPtvzD6D/CoS@vQPUEgfao5uva0wKMICAOh3mF8ZjquVwISYbH1p4WZJSgxCEyr9ZeeT5x7DP6r8fHtmzVbYz7wt@OtEbOEeS6MtHHW5l74nzEf2p0u6hs195@4j30ABqwsgiH9wwLWuAhhO2obVGehwIeUe56jfnSiwZMKECZD9rTeQtiT1xqvtwXgTLAGvHMuy8CeI0yKayByiiooB4Kkk5GUbeFglq3Q3eUbdWY7rSZtk2Ib9O5pT3T/b1y2zYiIp8gUUMVbbiN6wF6oEHEskYxGsqvY3ZBk5LbDugrol6HmPVi1O6S2x6AY6ujB5Uchx2RK3kctMK@pgrtmjgjYMRkJciAW5LCMxXyQON1Hz27ZvgOMW2xOwGVz4BNge7PgHmiEQLZbbelt0CBL0j66rkHTJu097EN5Kv/qqdG7zDemGiGLHas53/5vQ4UwOvi6fML0sytHQ/ANyIb3TdLy4qKL@S2v2QJzGAiSzxhA3F9DqXA4yAZL68d@1GjPqY9nj6vQeEuVoULwok3qOzvyJlJuSbKk464eu5PhLB4tz9oxlakEckRPNEcIubtG9Ff9GbN@MSgkFW@Q7CYzb4kbkrbLBdxzvcgc8yWUgKV@gV0rjqd9Ga0F3pXxsS84wDv58pVGuNvP1eOd4WMDfJtTmRUnW9Lb/ARyQi9JdlmhcH@kKcr80PT@YDO/Zk1s6NJvR70A63nW2DQ6TdEfQyGDzMjj3fEYtV60KSV59/Dqcnm/S2Q1fzW2vEWIGRVJrcfI3xEHASoISg7OM3i2WKT9IKxMt9eYE@m/@OlCBMkzTIomZjgcrF@bKHXw3KbCZ3x@O34aFKQ@NHo/tjm3A9BIKjdrih@ruZC6yONeNnj62w531TEq372xrUHdAAdUTCjZV4HITEsNotTKBZye09wsUERUFw2rnfEdkPOavT1rQG8TZyxJKiypI9Jca9e3tKIL4c@Nmhwho/cNlHx7TV/O9BpwMbas3btr9SqYOAg2hty9AVKyhy/whHCLcHwqm/xTlBn@HvTTOirU9G872@4lnup@gIV5JGJZEjCnugd4XPiitMx5Lafi8O9VBmCvNf/mL5UVa0vKjrt87KrDj@OgUOn3xxQq@VKb8u0LsmqDj0LvL/HC@hB6Lp53y/N22yTeMVDhjW23fuj7SWKNHJ0nNzfKFxe7qlyKNJjeLi9KQETrYua3np@qYZbayiO@6yGWhs9qsJZzzdV@xD@PyccZChFwzHTLec7ttQ@dWaNtb2dQega4ETI/sxl2AiJ6WXMbt9bBaAJ/Rm/WD1/h9bjLe6uWo/xgpjMYNNhhGgEHIZmmtG/S2qB91PrfJmOeoU2/LlMbBXuUBZBY5P7qyKlfSz3I2NwLPvlGqsrT8SJuFeDlNoDEdeVvKM7vpwo1srGoTUEwgDzcABkDbW0OoRfRDW25/j2rsLhZQkq@Wetmb2qZgx29hj70GVwlNHxOmJPmYx3CneLd5WJUnmfc/3xqmarnR0iMeTHaqTI522mHVNcF8nvLbM9PVKh26uOwIZQvqD8LaRkTMm87yAmPhvMAwnH37R38R7T68kVsF/BHoFSlYa6Bwfxvkzx@N7qrxPgaBR6ZIpoLPD@Frf3KdK2qso/pnRAn3YkNNPA@MRVVJ8rpVe2jzXPRm9GJnQc5Wh33xqTMNsaq/MI3MOO8psFXYYsGaRx@JJSfjVo@E6rtTWE@Lk@JLTYZOBH14SV@y16K1i5OW/EG36X4NXAGLNyvIcs6vV/iX00Xhm9ZAgZh53NgebNxMDBC/0zXgCnpI5HF/riSCSv71j8fGcw0VePN4HmKv72BHsZMsb6RryxBBVewfvOoPaWSWSoiqgzBq/1ROyryCIP1qjp@5aSXQ3d7mVubsT3xMxnJWsz7IArMMhs15Zz/wDEsTkpKkC0z6gRsxuoKkNxoa@e@43lhQDlORm9i21fJRdwdPOztdrL7B2u/ozNp/TVvtIX@xqpGeu3t@oGSKRhrih9LxNAf5/Xh7jkhCikTR@vr29zV1Zl@Uu4iwrRVI@qun/gNY1rPTsQ9UfhXfBtCLAenx2jg3abMIk04G/Vnb44geZJVw11LHrI21ugMo7wmPf9Y8m5kl2nm5KodczpNhza4w2pLYv0TAISBvr2BMH@0aO2rPK4qukdCx44s3p@yXiUoGqfaxJ6vGqMx@TxMJYnOrmRIVxPd//Y5DGdIYR@iSxIhjnRaUqs2FPbQl/6XOG1Rd5QpCFj1X7rdb@U7@piknGJ9qTQ2ytLwCpt4UUZiG2HV/GR21/vpYK1TvxdYyQ50bTF53XD7hTlejjVnARAx1uDMda8055g0uzjbP5q1vqdmQhrmupNgSKGNBrNHpEFy4R7c2hoZ@WBxQLZ7zc@wyVBFYaftSXeHKy0ZjWRVYK0NfcK/i9HNN4nI2upN@gZOrKTnu78HPwC7ayUNDJXpPPyZs3NZ2LGe5@VnJqkJPl3bWhzzq5C1jqvV8PpbmuRNvhJmrUkV1@vez/IKYImkrVxq7VS9AGu2JsgDw1V89IEzuHgXS6nkzIj4dBUTwGwFRRZeYyrEc1FzTotS7pBYKUufXtLHz7Nj9lj7pmO0bZjG31/b2Il6@LS8zFZMlwxo94e8vexQ7vHYz@03ynHNGsnoKKsi/tB@R24rkQeJp2brNMKb66GQPcqpyfmKku9T1Yyg77pgN6qg6lLZFfVzLWC5oLUGs5n/ee/6lgLvMG20emRpEPPsKfgpgR1JPbV2UczXSv1@HjM4wJxxDHro1LE1D3JOK3PUMGZ67rVGV3P1CLWKlFr6wS8lLEmblFhFipa2bhExDALzaSmo4qmWFgJr2OtMiWo8mSkQIvSMfq6l65KZPXHRNvM6YMLwRRDw2a146ZzdEfEmQSyqIdYkrKqDsnyOqTkP/@VuTaWLO0BEUL3KnmyNn4rRVzBw5EFqYKgToDqFZKlqKkWiAOZDNbMBDtpINSi6e/EBS9k0S5Iome1ZBWTMZetJuNV2pOm7bi3AxfCnUhdx2G8ct64Ze9j39MjRvwvv8c4nyy@2X7iCYd0m5tegZw8o1xtBwcheBNqp22Hc5uVLdxFQBbNr4XK2l7kQDcprtUS1BHZgEDkTpyRJahkWYiCxhqu7Af9oIMtYzgJarPSxA4dE7NH4KkadBA3wICRzYPL3LJAFvTgckqMcjinv6P7KCsegeaCLLyZDJFxBe8olljNBvu35@yZlNiekMmrqc/r88dIdg4fYqdnxKWJHRVX1N9@czf3sZ67eTh9z@gr5tzdzX/C@q6BeyoYK4dfM1iB0sXU06H3jP3uO51f0Dbbs/3EXMMAtfzwqZwrp6u1eK1eBW4@m5k9yKjaiN9oCpQFsk6or8pkqwKwRZNE/fPaY61B1m8A7nDQhzx9ihujnE5qezkMAbVYbfPYDk3nGgSs9u3Yn4m@L74uboW/BrA0U1eiLS1Kl4kgWTJj17c1qHslW1guWN3BtlpzBBeU7FGFhEc2OgZc8gCXvpBH9OtcmiX4kXhAMX6eUe/j2IcCeLWBeA2ATFqnhfk1w83M7c388/8HOR5Du/aPzTHB8W6OEeK9HAPgJhqJkYnnCvVKejcSiNNmXxr0jDTcotgldcvc4WJKl2ptplhpJtKp0K1F02vdqtNTSSedDpS3LrYM0G8n1ZHMYeuoXcwllnRc1kGTdzqgmtoLAzUbqHQvWbpkrl/yKLTtAJjlXTe0btpGIawee72oHjTXTAAt9q0Z@ZDAEcw6tWcX0J3I/PDP/9zc@XNngPsPLfecTcDbH1tvXXD/s1UIx8Hbv1i/@eDtZ@bbNwyy8vU2BzM3ayYiAxu5Mq2TfhGyaMTPt3KPbRu2nZIClrk0Al5PCesQ3MzWhjMbPI7bBnAeigvYjkoa9TJJT9TuHbhI/Zhh0BTBkSwvWSUjzs1eEVmz/jjBPVvQlDChYCjAQbdA9ExXCMm60x4uyzAROp3HIJXUVBrHvm0L9OnpKW3TBV4WY6ETk@XMIf@N3/btmtBDgKVMq@WWhjgQZRMDws6saI5D3sU5MSpWTjtnp@9PwCAxSxDaNAdxAIgTvZXVwkxoNFWLVSAeijg3iOJfrKwxMIUUsi5QNHfurRB5AJGJG3cWvZTyzeILXJe2Jffe7WKwNRGsimDHtn1CdvsNfWfcKffWDjMaBOZXe0ROAfcf7dl2tpae@Ov9To6Xu5UwN/SnqqLigpwMUEs7fIzPz3Ah51adslmogF6sQd8BSqgzUAcFURqoYz2eTOfypXL11X4dAml/CWan7WenrjuP1317v3bYX0j9iqmJDFO9TGRWrNymajOmjRCbge2XZO5L7SWlb6TeNFe9vE6bBLxKiGO/FDHpm3kyZO7nNfZNKLMFmDRn5V@l6nA@Pd/en57dKQevkv9u317GA@8RChe47nSyk9FO79E5udVanhpuWte9q/WhPttmp@56Da35vvF@e8fNegv8ZtvNatUQRdZLr5dLU9431hNB3r2MmRTZc2IStqIXdM2KVA5J3SQoUK/mJbapoa28vN6tby0LXjOpZHZkyZZCXoE@jCYJJrROFLTZ3SX736DDkzM2fSTod2F/nHQFF6TbA6piPSLQkciIKq@tlvSuQ6riSPLUVvSg4thso7H2j/Qhb7LUPuFjt3N6vTz2vd0kXn0sS4YDt7bMvdidhNw4nJgB7hT3hsydp9F7axsOvdot4yIbbsoT4FdZHdObLnxKXLkq0IujUxNADmIg0vnJCOC65FERsZUQ6aLqgcjAR/uKiFvcYmLlwTvqBCF1b1@cd6QetDQOpxtU0k84brNVh8e9Jood9LDJqnNcvLHNmB@1vWiLY/wt75WUjjh34Mr/43vkDvjbZ82p3Wl7JQNkj5O15afzcrPTSlnwhlVrNxuFXiiEaHStCHbrTjTq7esULl@GHgikWDW0AjihDXV0R/yYdkzIbjGd9tLk1XHnUNy6oTlpzxm2ZzNaoV0u0neBBwnw0iRml7gkGQdFHbjJ2sHEoJzRV1c6@FhKY/qW83rvwU0ScdKHOPqQBHMD@@1OCkxTiHJM0EIDDH/HSNEMemlIkfk8JMlSZL8HQO0NJhW51ycVEHhBck2ffb3ZPLFVA02uRqPHVmnsqsMoDWJxukdjANo9am5lmwJ/rQWowDVUYgCVhE6pBArl04WoKFBfHSAzI6idND8BIdOc7tVpIe7N5nGSwoFJYtZa0QqE7m4qT9ufZBXsmUPmhPSAT56h3f/2Dhv@rtX0L5j/lvEyJ0@OQzm2YMAYc545DvsxzuU/crkOlSPHoYLmyNdfY8f5@RCsnQevzWubA5DnUHaegDyDdRQ7VE4O@VPHYSfmOyIx4NXlcj5BhO91xvt0yD8zh1@DNeEGH82snY5DnezzYr1e7hnowxpyyLhBZp5wvxM56wOTP5RcLqTBe/iABHzP3FVdpF25qzKkj35iGblMb7RSI7u2yrokXp1dYjLQ8j5ea/Qg2ZxgTlo@rIC3t5TvCXvXur7AdR40GZYWdX1bvnZDvlyxWAoNlZOlZBzmRjtg4NwBTMRXN@90gjL57W8PuBD0@j6G/A7V9THInrjsQe7EfkAffLIxRzbN9nSX8kxp0WO/7fJB7@N9eVguXzvvHHSUth8kSzYuYPuGjvqOGOqAOWK/CzPMt99@C@YwfXvmPfPeO2899vtbh9mhC9Nn4fCROxQ5cn@yP2x6kGHa6fD5nFBod3SQvgvz/JEr4PuknEBIFC8/zYET7xH4cXQwSKfx@rv//e9@8Xc/J3@/IL@/kSRprHc68FP79JBewjXs0vhP3MvOlptHd7u7dEA/A8zPGKkaXNluD/rt1W9wR@fHD/BH/uFav@L9A/GxvAnI6@sDdXAmHCwPOI47WJC/B3Rz863LM3/3YjjOd0fjlnV/6MMnGtgqush1fPxpwz/GFo7YVJX49CGJIK0e0J3SVh997sGLOlgdjsB3azz@0bU2/lUM/GsMG0NPY1gR8C8xxL/LNv4Vlvi3RVYk5kaivo/FXO9e9B4/r/dh5UIc355@G/tHXPSPvObUAfTlDs7O7p@fXZ5b7zeukxPrH7TgyfoNL9MF9N4/ezyn35y5XLeE7tszKwOnnvszMzfk7n345vTe5XGd3p6eeh/OzuZnnvtvzm4xl094mz/j3WeDinV3hM7Y/LRiYkytUO5SWzATuS0XoO9Sc/tOPQe@TDzp9lXriQMO3oKbVwz042slHU@V6gBdLqTj1fR5rpGul8Ffv384@/TJ5QVB@AT0nt3fAkk/cZ25YoZh0DcPR94vYeDDHpf5Sh2kzuZ1xnMKRBcwexWSlgdYcf8dvt8e3DpcH10fWZmdstyQG16qpc1/qTSHAGnODlSN7bN9rgNVhWbFOrtgF3N2pJa4DjhF@GNH4JTY7jxQCpU@zdkeq7AKx@2ge/t/VFIvSyogVCGaMWcNxM124dkrlS4BWReSH8CfxLLsHOics1P4Z2WOXN88sJBbJ3t3R93Stm9FUHdezu5l7d6Q3S7dB0Pjx6dnX@jxllhnwej9Le5WvbfRbvvD3S0oM/v9yQGj390xpnK2@QK2E7Kj9fn54SEVr8UfHhgc15qfHro@uTyf4IqduU6tx8eDztnJx7tjD4rcSvgOmNOPd2d@D7pDLuC5D/xOGdePvDYo4fnhjrI7Zs1mE3/N2XRmuojD9LtrrkPx1mTAy3ShF1wIyuyLv@uYv5Yyh@M2eP/0DG3Unf3EbrViDppsDrdxd3Nfl/bZsKfgiDrBUOD8aI6GgrTz7CwUBI9QxOlxsNiTMKPc2cbj8Z3NS8ZOvGSRYiwW1zR@gf0lRwCQOKLBWOzOxmsPd7Zb3z3GDXqiIVrVPFG/0@Z0fsOdnkIamITPCd42@9ymanb66Xn7z/H0fOoglxP/nE70dILAkOeZ0wEAziC8zZ8c9Knj1IF@4IXxnp7P0EngnsB163DeO5@fTT@4O5ynJtYzJzCOBiPhv9I/tB3///m/rNM62BrPB2j9KnQg6HS0F6IzEHJEXFHrL/YBGOuw@e1@NGvsvP329tOR/ygcuP14f@Q9wp/j9O7sfk8T6wRjB@ryqurFuAMsWNRX3pOKjfPZ7Og@ODgRrO3wstqj/dETtExOsGXG2Da40EXZaSjVs9O1HG8aHucZCgFNipV23tPO5yeQbTMQzGSHNdN0dzdnUcHQTvqkHTt8OuCfTw4wBfrZtgK3qgjB77CfkKlI25PtkNduuXvbs@3wqf2M/YkjzklMyWDg5OQoYLrDEXBzR05zdB0MvpO1G0JEnRdOUBedHKAI24GbzoM7KtYWe4APcjverqWuYDD4gfHBY/6TUNo3P7Kus6M9V8QXcR25Pt0eQecKS@We@H73gTrBmT5zWtHmsZl1nY5ECRkHtK5HadC6p@Jh2TVf/R2ljkwXh7/0B52CznCbVqCzGWbpDnT/eY1Wu90Ppj/06um2KELHSpTl1TEK0PeTOzOpI4KZhjYmGLS6CNeozIsTUZxNJjNxfSUl/ZgfDPgxuX741U9/@NX/8MOvf/bDr3/6w69/8Ztf/uKn8Psr@P3MfP7s30eDeP/NL//F//zDX/waPP8Gfv8Jfv/xN7/8V79n/sj738Lv/9zy@1vrtwVn/ijA9ce/@eXP//I3v/xnfwa/f2P9/uzl74c//Q/m//9l/aHz1z/86d/izXr56c@gLP/hr3@F/z//63/4T7/C///l3/7DX//Lf/jjf0ccf246/u9/8@/N@9///k///r/7k7///V@@cf/pu/dffoH/L/8r@Hw5nV@C50vy9WN9fvk70fOP4cYmFZABkLQ/@uFf/QHI6p@ab/8U3uCfdnnMy7WC@UP0/e6QZcEou/tuG/Q7hgNDiWa2PP@Q/u4OtypwG0hI4l9/x7Bg0bHMd7tIt0H/6De//JO/BN/vPtHgtwL9gxUCS/HsgK5Jhd86E38I4H9hZdCE@8MffvV7P/zlf//Dr/78h1/9MaoyDx2Iuul41O3h3rF3DwAw6I6/D2QBhr4EDgG/qKvyQAEq@P9Af6B8ND7xRln4PxDX/IgK@kERr9zcxu0PEHcQ7vuw49Tzx087Xibuo33ABPAjCf@wl1hM44h6K@8fSbSPVviHfQCfIBiaTdJynuIdX8AnAV08q6cXO4vQMcpNR2L0GZ1AwBi8k3B0kndoZPEc2RiVWkHQdAr4gS3wfA7dv2@xE236n5mg9BlFf0@gLTQxE9H3FHha8b8naGMYZz6nCDb8tyxXdONvFbC6kVfK8pibwPNXHhRkyE2ig1S21OPj2PdcIEzBk7xP8JgcbJrwgLU5OQPVC13YU6gdGOHsyXN6Opp30VlN1wCiVqI5H@ulb9n7p0DYFwgGgj5/KBQM@7hAKBoIBSN@lmNDbNDn46KBQDQSDT/TUersmp576XL5yvMMqOYeD@NDnHSMC4ZPFjGIS7yoMxwKjpmt9OLJo@s4YU/dEQvhCWdssZf75MHMfQUXTX1F0V@BF1yeZ8o80QWonGFGyOwAbc0f5Eon1igznvtljjTbuGDU9kJWnLTHE9V16k5UOmaCVJiul@FWyZ1na1vPWjqezFIhOlEqpl48ghZQkC6kM7X1a9gMXUUNrlG00oXCy1frgebLBzoYdru9Xi/c8OkmF3l6D79ZgXBv97APbEGbLcT6wjYbGCiejzZ6IdJ9ekT76ZMxlD4YNU8ez3NPaovUJc4LRzlzQZ@EuMGliVFcwgRwM4WsIGvj4YeT8due8EAvdGpSr2/QxkxdA@i6Plt39JqrXt26d9ek2zyPvx97QQLi9mW872GYaRC/VyHya3AqCybgCE8wwvXkBo5KSl2apbworT5fNBKMRP2@iDsSjQSCXCgYdHM@NxeOhKOsm2O5CBeKBIGz7kgg6g8EsH3gfMFomDoAWZO6DHNEHXA2G3lKioAHWZziiSCqt39GHXTELi52o@eOjpM@6Kw9JhHa5o/csTREtHEhCheeHM1j0PHHJTl@juZslI2nBfogk0mymYzNlsAXaFTZJGuzdfAlGGHZcMJmE0lIEqqwDyL18S0dYnFXoE3Cl2Q8k0EMA3zxRRCHzTY0Q8wXefUSBjAFX/x@REDbbI9rdCwgV02KIiSWYb6wbCJps01M8iLwB3Bx8y1AiE3jCwZgpIwZkoQwm@18FQlsBZutYsJZSWVX@Y3Hbbac@RKPI4o8yXzQzNQFvsTJBZE0eAPhtdl64OhpYN/bbG1wogjbbAK4hAUPfiNw4S4axeBttoWZD8yJzTYn0LwwtNkeVv6QDtCTzfJ9oyP2zGuhmU8BgnIQJM0n6Uz7/Lzd67W1RTx9XiFB@XyWHywmWrvXtiK2H@BSMRYEDUeLl5eIQQ8PvLw/6AKClBdBD4sHkVD4wD8CZdbVw4RGD3kMykPQvrFkCyFcIwBu45UYwTPBt82g1UWCyHPebttOQGgprD70wuF8IoNaDlqXliIoHQfrnkScnuDHScQWCtuOj@Bp@2jzg3PuoFk7dGRt9jubzXkbvf9oCwdtx/aPHz32r7mPtC0ctR3bwmEb7TzRRGOiKbTv5BnTWcbYE3w@4qF/NO/GOx7R5Xyy4Nonz9hQQC/66dGxdMU499L5EQlzQHc9YHMeA6EnzwxzitUfqys81@2W1az4IjZQp@C9AjD1xLqeQxsD2pyGn8dDYfg4ZubZYYs6sOsPBEWjdzbSTzenlhx2e9hntzvtJ4DkAzmWjzbpRNoJfavc20DXQO6jPtsq846oJ@qK0p4oUP6KFm14rBu8hpOMJKlj2haCZhG88bjB6KvG5BNYoe7jo3bw9OyfvLr@m3@y79rvixdlNvUhjjp4pjp4FEYgSp9ET6iDJ@r56fn0bJXqBb1Y8C7P6vVrmu65DqlDO/LA7t8d5IvH4r1KfDWcEU@Cke1XA@rB4eEhdXBaO7P5bSXvw3oE84whA@F3OEqOY8reu4fTD67faXjT4z37tJoDANIZShNx1W0HT3Q3hxkjQSyUHq0fuH7HCxKhYoCTOsFhIdsB1j5BVic4TUPfmRk6/f6ADEPS5afuRCHLLo4v0fxx8MdVcj7R7T3IzfdFSX6K@D1nZLYQ5fqZCIZQIhM51IGiWk7gozoxDHFuQDUIBtFqckKRjavRb8LfRL65rJfqpcwn9jhyHCFMv7uzZMXN2Tk7KcaHT9DaSZU0dFC@U4Pc90r@5OB4bPcH7P51yd3FDkw2cWHnwZkv7NX5xcG9tdnAEQDPe3Py2ccdNHev2c7LlEx5UAeRy2@xW7c6UFzyERfD0PTh8@kz/J89356ePp/isj144L95e342w8k/krZ6IY/NtQO3gdmE/26C5H04uP/ec2r@n@ItWTKZYAsFbc6Db2NnULz6Nw/fPByAmonSNh8pFBdjDiKN8YMOeB0p5E/Uj/Dvm43HEUQ/Wr@Jp0c6HTyDLhT4MQxz57zygUUTjYYioQPqt8Cwd5ZOQeh6LUFXFDV9Mtq3mCCuSZc8LrRQ1gsKwHE5WeK5pZ9Wp8avTB8abR9cLYPGz7afZQ9teZGPLez6LXQGl3ajL0WhSyJf/qC7qGcdONhqkCW69BHuqMMdLE7qifoKcE0Eg6wKh9sJRX2Fy5Px1bGCc9Nf64YTe4Wsk/rqK6vV0A2vbjwgcoxkeXq4E@qZQvbwnY5Ok1NbcY7A3PbC42JfdWzuO5cXtBlJJ62facWRHSuY7hbBR3TXpAJyc0STFAnlmDkz@a9MsPaki6RkcoU0xIF@T5dM61uxbVobzzQm2fvQdVqJ0yx4IRYEJ5wi4AgI6MDTQXA7R7i3RnAQSBfNYXiXLA8AKDBq3YQSN921It7i6z1ER/Rd0FU6IDZTd5g5oI8erGStPKwaY8wEsBBzR1o70mhrPcFtlR6ex3Z776SfViv4HRgK3XvfZouBhQsKw/weCYkojDrW@ayxDZsJNu7eDUV7Yq4Ed6zhLJ8No56pI8M9OjGLanxCXTgE5xOuSzn5fvT118I349vR/YlzFDPw6XKNoOkdOiQT5MiIjWIgHuNb6f7EuHW5pPvYyHnhwHc8BpkF4K7JbN1p5Q1yrsSAFlxuoTvdy1vF871y787cKi4geeI@uokt3XyMdc/hJ4HdIrsfY5yVD0jTiC1dygl/Cj9cIrOzyh7sDxd/suOFUYYOOba85e9jwA8ZIrpcGcgM0Knfyi7XvRMSlyHwdcQT@euveZd8Nj@RPR4nQn3j/5i5NcBx74rh@7GDP51/XN5OIP6xA54xSEZ2AvEQz@L185p2oO8EeGyW6YZ0k8Y5kjcH8kax2NHNx6Obo9iHD8vbuWd07zbZf8xupAGJnyPxJ1u7GBxHN076BUvIjInD9hPp@CdeUI42t@RyAZPd462YJoVHNxAydrlWVD@jviRfSVgtv0IJs1bemwe@kpMeyWpKcvauTo53Njq4BwnixnVBkixwc/PYWIKONI@7Kt3k7GOeQGCY9dkWDLybf/xIrZK2FntDyqhc2iLNY4ecHNqv4fQN@QSQuYH0c/p1nxpe6dx1P7Sau0nT0Of1h7aqK1FNpMLpmnCLIKgGntjnE1NjmUv8QdkQ7QEwRHsgnAe1CDLJ0hMWZMwKhNJaFRDEQj3RNTc/40GhOuontJDXNR9UiEkGVOY9ZEjuQYzoJpAnCVy0dErSAwdUFeoryATSgHmQ7ukzUGT011/T1utpDLrxYWwLEAzhBi4OgV5RCol/AaWAA6kcgIyiPiSJAG1fYQhuYdlJKPCPS8jageaACK6B29yI5iUb0RwTRTf3XyLfnCYZWBZffTVwxQIWQfBPuh4QH8Kef3tgNffHdLJ0Wa7X0pXLeBXu0HOKbB9vvvqEyKsPB4zxgwBtSSHbMAS@womtvEDTDjBmDTzKEb8Q1KHz9QLt8xVTbjx4CVh/YI5gQoN6vMYk6uRQW92raj1mJg0lZvd7ZPgxF7Ljg3z9zLM6Bx3JIY2zvNkVutkUquNgGDTm1mkxO0eOj0Rdt76H4Fl9Y4ps1yf7Y0e4zRNqofX9BLKYdrUekKw@xflFN1nTrEk9iXw4qG8i2IlPzsk2zOikflD43YMOb/Ao0VQ0wrLHNOtGB7dy@FYO/8oRWDmCK0do5QivHJGVI2o5uBVmzsQM3Vy/P7RxhjfOyMYZXTsD7Ma5wRDwbZz@jTOwcQY3zk1qgXVqoQjBSx@suEmqrqhhGBeIrMJwVzd0adAzCGi4l54BINT3ChKiB155QnqRXc9wlLUSyjElBPL5Qpt30D4r2JjDpMpt0uE2UzbfLE9oqyiz80YENq1poJXSc/zQCwid85jGXW4UBWqXFmSRB2NANMBKiWVA/kXnsbn7W1scb3a6IYYYt36H6HiKOsThyDeLTPHZE@zbF2xi8@3FZm6fp9eM2domaBFpUnm809KaGAM7fttYP6CCRY6@AeEzIbAMdvcVrtKsaZO9SfrfT3IH4d4kXxFl4g3ui4W8cRDksVVU0v4TbLFVeqadIpLSBjPA@kIdkYEXBYrHAMSeuGPbb375Z/8r/Ztf/vzX9A9/8ev/5z/@T@j@D3j738BmoX1rgJ/9HG//Gm//kiYTmGRidhOJwPuPbT/82a/g9X/8d/QPP/25GfQnf2lzB9aIIAS9NjF/8U/x9gd4@z9s7uAa8Bd/ZAJiFJv7mdoxrRwA9bO/oWlIDbGskf3ZX9G0zQUGhsOSvFuzjt9vbRo2EazZcEtc9y/DzTt@3wN4zDpdNsBrvXGbNxcWgHMLucbjJ9c2dQ/MGXMKCbW0wAt93Bhqeak62j8CmjCq7u2BvM06YPRYgxh2yP3v08e03YUwTlwg28E@DtHhVv6tfNs2oQjrsjFAHX4BwUJFvn6ypgS6txTIN@kJLHQvdltIj5QzZcTibxE/6bhqQGwrySIfg6CstFaxodNDWx/GIl8HWXV1UWixGTJPDyAfxaCsnYvcVoI76uZFsUEqL32gy7jZT7wdlXiIozEUCURb8xsZiy@EC@6X6DYlZ1WbdCnzosLg1QYTc7itkdYJxWib7TOwyGkL3okWl38X3qTXArhlj/33O7uT9wHbrq@vbdSWH4sypHUcBMNWpkyVsQ7idoN8W0G@rSCg2cRJdE3Q53tBA2k4UC/u7sQ3o22pqN1oG@HCmrMqByQD@oLmMKe7K0/0fuw1aqKRd5Xda@RbKLn7mFVP7hSic85om/NVBMC5Gyf2siz3o2ZfwbwuqP0xkds7Pjul9TamnThblYJwj3rJpXXJcdF9Jbeb4DuouXvXFybkY/@RCXm@MKFQ8PMJvSxWjLuD/m3@fl7trNTEWsNvkJkV/2CngcKm8c9A9DbqCCnWiNPhhC5P3OrytGcq7djzBTTwZ1YnLe589kzbOn8ROzFF1RDN4YFPYxW6HCpawVvfTd33wWTrM6U9RdVEffvUAcncl6nY8dwLQe0p0Kq58cRHyfqmH07Pmycc7bYr65bNskKT5qdYEbXJKLQ8Hx4kRTIeHsD4lLvODQPx1SvgZjk7hd9wBddWfMfatC2NHSqeXGs4P4@T2LtmtJokDB2lsRVoh0TiNHToBFGGzhfdx6876arJEsyi@b0nsEjbhoOcMNVXR2pPVFQ88gNjv0Cf2@BGgvjxmNDipnk3LWxRZHWiHYKbd1pRL350VPrCh98nW8X37SLYYYab1l7yGDmr7Unu4c3kzGir9Ko/nt7qNr3V9@ntSppuvKSZeOJoDz5/XNJ@xwYDAG7I8H@eDLd1ys8rcnZIWXvjlwXNCF9MYkfUBWj@kNI4gMYtcG8X5MO9ftPJtjiL8MZb/H@/AFfR019afMSYrS5A34zIh8BIF00nZ5wpgugA8JzTuVkzuJXcWrRTX5iW1dEhPTw3bSOKS8E9l1Axx2NR0ddrrVaIPyPzuG7oldyTxUQxM3APTdrUTQ99bxdR6qEjyvxC7DgsSPcW3lWOKyLfIfrqyzKOio4oPdX8nKSDdXM7phjZG0@Ajt8QGd49dTrfFisTRFpLD5mMIxTm3uYfGbh7qZpxEDRmzoGoGmjQA3J8Fjm0bLwYL8zzNGTzM9aWHjXbH7Mki3jMyGcZAnwwPynHuTfJOt9TnxXHOktf0CKsYb27WSa7UlfNlgrW@Ksy/HEs@nxOySjDOlJsVco71slbJS69V@JbUrGSSdMq@TKR/JzQfbHMbYmaiWyjwpI/rgl5hTnJy7IgOLYxmj7vlpiqvNIJ6IclpipvtCoPexTqOibRdAZ@eSdm2hdOSgJnDp5TeDbgiQihD/pgCtQqb2jXroa8SMiIH29ZLZbPrYC26BYXndvziFtQ1MqNA7nP6zSFN9MUXqUp7KS5rgG7SW4BUcJOklYpYPG8VwSy2DXe0M4YhD13eLyntuFSVF7Dudcnu2Q/lty0fWo/BoVsF@3HaQcoZXvHfpwiDt1@XCWOof34AhybumX/zn68qhYIoMErcXxCf0uF47tgP046nM8Ufs9aX6XrtR@vyxRgPpqvhCPP5vBq25r1V9ejqiJ@KxSNSjeNEqPDQ8Vs3d67yY@FfwJqnUkJgR9itO@IAGMHZKfR2GoxzHSg2fCSj6M79jUfx6uhKWt8YzOGAuGu2NagCkrJhOgj@4F9VxmZhGEoGXyEJxCIevN4P0U096pn9jlyrNQl/EorMHs3fcI9L7EHOg4SfgvA24M48ib@qrx2UZgF@GV0YuS36HxFzio5QhEuBnDuIQuZ@q39nUxhWb8439As/e0Sej1GgIXoWYGYpUTQbul0sOHQNiWJjdXxrpCQUJztk7bj4GVVSpTeF9GIVrBq5hvBxNvKGSqG7crvfC87W/GQtB0VhIG37L1Zy9btAtHFGLTRdVuWqln5gIQtndMhBw6JKLYpy0ngTHXjJm3FW83QKq6ZJNFcu2oSIntxf@@EN8zUN/MyuOv3x3VfVzHBBAcaEcFWzHUqpn5Vf4T9rpr2@8qgXjHhRQL7DOv9Telr8/rdVvYF5fIm2dcFiIFuOuXcaxytU9iwHHoHW5b5e7L2ysTHDzKaRr6Z6Br7C2t/xbZ1n@AzfHvZtzBxoZWgTXc9hzgwO/S9zajXFok89a6MFi@mZOExM76mdJO192k1M76viDEE22h4/OgC1nYLeLvwEB/JgPaC5WYtx103ZJ5iXbfJsTGbmQtz1kHFVWLr0zq3PEHdk/Vr6yVa4FF6qKRKxUILGt1wOOx8PRWBtRbibtpx6t1pgnW3xefGA9fMz6uruJJGMz7cKbbXS8qIBxgDPJm3McXPquNOS5dt6fMXdRfimbBbHLVwDTfVgN/RSmjq8NhkSxZfzY@BOI54C8nKvAV@u0lvDWeNUDpwQufhgTRfDw@4OOfhwWrFsGjW00i/PbC@B@rbrNegDnZXMxGLS391qhEOAExG5vfQrQE467wicx0Kbk3MGavY61gTxZBWix1wfMj6/Lo5l@/wczg6keuufQgduCjD4QtgF9YXxOMSzFgIjQOfZGmllc4H09DBY7v1saqQg1fJYXbEbMdDxPXV0Cshe6LMeLIMxEyFnPKwRZG5IGs1L2Z@9F0hB1JDXNxLR4aQV7xx02LPS2Z8fFHocgylsXke53rph@4kkQjBZI0W8LgtiyMgqQqyu2c0@VKCUulnpF4PBImxvnBjLnCp8RDVo3Y9ydU5Uwd0g5elzurEY2tNGDlt3BoHBnY6dg4K02lfCKypqBs4u/kBY3GZDI2HgbFkkRaBgl8YHmHTGXFvxf3gWDh3n9zqciK@D44HLFlz062k4ddspryyxWdrL@7W0LQ1aUn0wNbM5epoKso6ozBG5im9uEZt7LAd2FZnVqHTXDbBy8LqCC0HHt52TH2lEMWDK8BowVxbAwaugkYbmV5zrpekKvRPaL@PfKEb0iNWKkkWcJgzezvYIQyiIrHm6j5Lwdh@0rH9BCcTqa8OUBeasobxV6KMbnL28UaW6Q8WOnNCBauyWQVWL8GtFz90Nb7ak/AHh80FWFw2p20HE8Bbsx9fmZr3dVRQis7fMrVOqJlR4/F4bcRplfN4L96PV1rwnmALruYgkGaYdFbuxFO59uJcDdemXR9ba10l2n5XOdyZj6XsKJkdpykp0Bq5bvzzaDawDCb9ybjAXnfPC91AOHndvdbFuCxGmelgeNURK@M2p@nSRfGyWFkymfpVo3c16N40m4OwUqXGlZtE72ouXkWayrRRj@b0K7GRLBrD4sCYcItSuBmqzxQ90agl@vlFbjac50JqSwomr8RwozvOzoRFcCxk69TNtNYPVbOLYZQbdRbxpN5phV0uppVM9CJZoXPTzVeTF52eFmwHh9Uo75@O8t3xon@RVR4Lg2R1KrjGg0wuNKWUcm46EwPNYVvOKjeVRqOdSpRnQ06/GXcGgeblxGhHtJDfP4mL/UEgmJsYWqSQiF@EjVQ818jI1w3jZtGIlCkja9TC9bwQlV3TkiH4J6k6o7ONeV66qM5CWV9NzSp5OTcoD88n52V5PBmmAlKpNgpovetMW/X5slfVabZVoLRAvtmKVAa@SEqYC8xFUFVH/lq0WNAu55PEY0lsJoVqQmyH2ETwOs0NLksLoTQtVCrN8rhZH4X1C06@ybADqnQtVOOJYaYwinC14iIXOc9VJ8lkbj5t@7o9NT7pNP2X16FZoSjmmleMP8tPjEuXlCzJzCCf1xeN@kXuuqjfQLW@zEuB7mKeaCS07mMqqV9WCkxRG/argYHSGTfCUlIV8uVcwMgN49lZ8yaaSwzFbrk9VIe1ptycGFJqwGSoRXJ4VW@Ls4y0nPHpQKFxxQzSFcEIx3v@KjPodttDuaQve@eFZa86afc60dI5mxIfLzqJRrCSHnOXGT1QVBZUq5boSsvKVZcblqPZ3E07HZculWCyLI7L59np3OdrSd3yLLjk5teDTECaCwG2UEpcX7qu8r6Kq@BKJMqqv9SjfKnMebMXvHCpGXHJFLr8Yzjp0iaTwDw1mUiaWKgrsjYKymwkU3P1w7rWjF5eztp67rqSbAryMnJzORyGbirU9TSnq5ovks/Eo0x5yGrn/KCYuwlLSiYwS5zL6WiuuaxHjHRhIkeyhV4qX9FStZFwHU33qovFsBfJi@XCME6JkVSlMmj3Gu15q6qXF@xlQBi0XenzdPGxB/W4Uc348vVEqDep@BsXKWVarmVcS/W6WRgni0MuXY5MQrWwf0RN5/lIvGoo0jh1fhkNXU2kQjqe6tWTnCqK14/CBTfkq7UFG9HD2lXm@mqsu4xaWw20@wn/4uqyxTRudD2YlaibeTOUiw814aIzN/J6uKb41NIVy111i3U5OG1Kj62yOoiPmIv69ZJpz5aZedkQjOpQDXbCweH5XH/UlhfaBRVpDXi5XkyqhYEQumhJyzAT5JRaK9m9FFp5Hxuv97KXYiY77S3r4sg3yD5OsgIv6OV4q30uh6bzsavrj0wLVK3YvO6FHx/ZtlhsRaX4sF4p5wxfjWcmrWoh@Fho6XpGqOekREBSJqlE63w4St4s@Jo@X05qobbcXZQ1H5um5sXWZUMYqD09o98Ig@V15ka5nPhC16VBN2x0htxI4gqNLhsujiuulKssn7d7i1BjIk4FsAzHV7kxl4gPBiWqxI3C08QiqhvKuX5RbCfzcSkeL0R8V2NfODtMnmfnHalRbxSzHV4N3LST/lCp3WN9nUQx3SsHRr1wuRgOFJJUrb24qnCdVETi@rycHOQXgXG04EuEmMaskr0a1PpKUU7Gm/Nuwi/U1Fm4yXeVurgMhZlL1jXoR/NKnA2UQ1TdSBn1QmbmdykXuUtfebEQrtv8xM93H1u6S2gt@8tSQ@RVuV94rHC1xqSQlAaDRigh1NhSospOlvqMHxfKVDRVVrhUYT7NzPrVJquPU9lxpD0vdpLlstged/zjbrsUn3fZabN5c3VVLymj66tRthJul5YdfhBsGN1KqDQ3qEcweRrTQj3Tnqe6endQmT4q5/PJdYMJ1M9HhXpn6hpEb1pTv3RdYgvFRKPLT3JXvbBRL87Hl3m5KzMjX6nHULN6ebk0xLiaLs4uW/NuY7mMSwn9kZtfMHzhPJe6NlzRdCaeKtWqvCaXSueFVJwfzS5nheuwS1xWLztBafh4Q5UVRfZpN1U5nGD9uq8eTC2TwuCcnZwnRrV8LcqNuXq2cXl5wfVlYSSEW6VUqHkpNOPx/MUi3@Ub5fK4fFGvUSWXcn1zU2NKNbkQ7RZylZoazE21y2YzzM/U@BXP5gKj9qwwT8wuJ5PmKJp3tQyR96tLUeQqM7nAiFmQnQglTqblZLGsL3yPy8Fjb5pSrxvR@Pg8FE8uup2pOF2y8dTUxeiZ@awTksYRX601P@@2hMte76KS6PvH03EtlAxS@Wj3Umm0k/3L6EK8yBYamYkhVjvtgOTS2fGgdhWv63VhIZ0Lof60rrdkqHzdcbCWSEZ1@SYVudAkFxsREpTQvOTLTKEfvC7mO@osOb9sLFLQ5Yhw3TIbVBdKYxIZKtkLPXHRfLyIRHr1dnYICU/6N31BqrsSnbZ41ZWL1M31RWOYLk8azODq@jJcrmddkaVfO38U1P45H13UliWWFbvR3jQ3mfvHBSFyHrkoCXJ@XqzUu2IvVPVdyefKkkop4T4b73Kz6UxhXItgIpLudRP1oqKl6kI2LKplnmHmzRuj1LyOXPjO2Su2OpqxPv1yxrDdliItWsVWy9ehElP9YtysctO0K2vEW9VBRTiXmWKzkluqi0Lap9fjxWT3YjJbjAsLSfPfCIXzpFwWJA7MkmCoV9Pqw2Vi2qaa3XkhmYiEb3xZkCBdl6OzVoAXBX3cmw@YwuUkK88Hk2FDc43mTMV105oHo/1GX2eEQqFWzM3SWlDN6wOFCoUEX7apjcN65XG0yCWNVL9RlwPJaKPXLmVbzGWtexG9SlZvwmKwzOQexWizGmKFQrApMFxFHU0NaJGE3pAqLNiOJsiixocnpcdgejJxdRbTieEa34TPLyLN3jDJTQXe5Y@31Ud@3sjLrFQMiz291JxNrzNNsBCVxrSuUJmb@th/IWW71WyjdDnkyvHK0mAS0aZwHei1NK6rdKcVvxHM58ReWOim0jfDQSqbe8yxre4jO@Nk7erKn8lyVLjrShhqR2YaV@MrZenjxXirFLmcdZbJUb/YFbM5X0prVUKd6gUvp6EZlR4L7LiROS/cdNpyn@mqSqlaYVnqJuRLN68rj9y0c1Ve1tR5Vuvl42XZf93NKWr5usGlrjSmGE5krpKDyk1yEQmVNbkt1nqRmjJynftVgY8rhRAVFqdiotFk6qLk58LzZZsfigx30xwOI1lmGdKXTFzRZ4NIbxltn4@45k1RPa8thsz5aH5TTlxzE9HFcWVhTF0Zy3Lw/Lzpulic13M9uZ7rCgw/Wgz0bGIi5mftq1DcFRmzNVe60@jPC@XeuJlmwu12hKv6/c2A8dgpL/SrItVIFbL@cGphzLvp4aQ4j2TH8VB1Ma9fBQLDm8G8FKmGKsE5N1WH6cQ40wsy6rUeVua1bC@TENPdy65@uWwLIyq0nBRzmUjaFRT5Vrl1w3bTzGO1Ixv9Xrd2ce2vhhghmC2VZzc3qTgzCncH6Zx8Dm3ijL@cL6qD1rB9VdL9EqWWWq5caBlaVm@uih2l3Mxf9tuzXjhc1rKNQXSybI0rUsU1XtZzbfU8VR7JqeU1CFyoEg0O6nK63pSuUxW2RBmhZnwGNjiXKEiLHpMLshddhc3PR@fR61EzNGwNG8lppTUfDkLVcFCdiMuw0XwMTsR6uJUfVRmh3Zr1Xb5zSq0uF9fpq4BWKM7GBaOsihdsxFe4GdZH6UndNUpeZNpGssmO275mYTZxJYNgFUQuG1FfsX0xSOSG51d69soXpWoZaTGJDM5D564yNCaTgV6KNGSfPGWajNyYTcXhiOWLKb6hzdv1TKFT7PgizNglhWfGRegx3yrf8MY4oDCUvgh1ZrwrmwYLIiW1glVXwxizI@iLsNdT/4XS8/t05bpaFYykGh7W/VExkNEaitqYq4OGT7o6Dw9ngnQxoBLishOQ65VmpzhfzjrRYaDDV6f1eOZaafqTyrg/1zUuFL3wNfjH8kjzl4xxuVAXEsrViOe7M9dcTqQuteqU6vSK8U4z8zjpThuBUjwQX1x32MDkZjrglOV1uuUblNvxfndWaQaWlZk/0TnnlMpIGo80H8PWGkp6GJnXs@IFlV@mxUU/cpUoNwL1i0F06Jd7w2qZXQxLUle4udEnXK7VK1xxnVywkbiKDrNdPS6G69FufsDMi@3STSjZEQMs5ernRowvWRD8@fS1y8gLcvBRWnJFYxntKotiXWpXe9P4uNAZ1CfFRJZJcL7p@bw08mcrjH/CJ0aR1IXW0mRKTAfj83rpMqT3b@JGI6CWfdPI@KYs9a59nXKfF0ZsKAI6@LLTvlnU45XErNAqZqt6XOktRZc2u1DOc5lMQqGy3WbxUX/k1e4kHqiXCq2rx6u41qsF24ae4@aPIrNYKKV8UhAWrXhOHxYb@aqSC7OjTuIyfNXvFJS6Wpb8F5QQDQ@vw4xSFfITVgyU44HMY@NceMxNQxV1qBhCLX3DGcUKKLtcsF4at2ajZbLPduf@QPpaL/U64xuorYMl5ZtkK61OpTtQ5rNK3mhc@EdVbtiYycOQwo9dgXS0VOK5nh87YcFrVRmp8kXPuK4Wpxcaw/SXoYk4PhcvJKrgG/fiuUoo7@PPz1upaJ0bPRZEX@QyMInPfKXKpUsJiuNUrjeS2eSwMhCvJOgyNEPlQZ6tFqV672aSvI4uqtSy1e5GlXxzpl4kh7PUcDqo1ed@6F7VGgVdr1aujU5u6mvnw3K71O/UUpnklZDkeT1cUpLp0nA8abRHs2wgSA0y/uvBZTgv9ULDcE5ctC4m42g5v8wl@9mAq6XkI0aLN@THkjx4LLYNo/0YlhrVqzzTTIQFhX1chI3rfpPRqWxklD4PiOFlrs@F68poOpl0ShVFzS3KV5fA5rDPXztvM/Fx86psNDpZUbjO1sHSz6tirnqdH1fPr7OdSUehZD@Ib5LRLs4LeuY6NbzhZrnKoi1xrmHpYlYKhoPdaNs1DY6K/UkqGGyGR/niNJMaa6H5JWj9XnlRLoiV4iXFjS5b6aEr3@W4iHa5bEwDlbh4HWpfzrqzQDAVnyv9SKTOzq/y58JVpD3OzUb1PNe7YmY30aE@4ut8JS6o3RKVeBz7F6m5kWaD6YtQ9vpKHIRmnfTEl4vPqs1cyIgWu81m4HFWmQ3FYobr1ubTma@cKV0ZSiA4b1zdDC@gFIKU0JtfpcPiZUDssNLyJqll1LZS5@Msk2d8s3rjyqX2lMei6BqWfRn/OJRm52UeesY3iUm@E2rXB3LzPJGN9qlOQEi7anoodxN6vH68lLTrgSs8ApUT6VamV5dgkrSNei0wv@pGW9yykYw0@XZmyaUvmHggm51Ecz5fvhAttCi9GhyBtDzOfNf5lOy7KjdqgYkrVUzNO/3qTb2SnF1GblrcqNysTvPYGfMz7KxbGlTqi2JmXpfEUHpYSXcTlCt3NdNL0XG3kmqkNabc6WYCg2H2PHMuTi6EyTytuNherr6YPk5GYiR/KfOipmQqRj8u@FuRoX8u5Mbxx4sGtcjy6TyXjDQi2lAS8oNiXR/o0@a4K8UDj8G5y6gMytJFMFWpXSuDer9Y1ITkpS@si6lhdRS6qQ/m7amY7uSprhGdCvL8vBgylMQiI13XL6/ynSq7EMqRfDGjzdk2k3msslODqUeq5VqvXdSkwgAaTlerrqoRGVSK0VevKH7cz7GzRvyiE@npyXM2UsjPS3Wp6GKv0pVByqdPNRfTH5V8qaWazvu7s3CvcnUxYrXktNN3XZTDzM0goc6KVNDo@Ju8PoxWulyr1WDG6cpS1y8j9bbr4kpmxIrvJpzILrla2z/uTPqtSGt0Pn1stS4f241qForz2iWGqpePVO/qIquHu1GB69QTyUJcnY7ZvDaqdAOjgtqq@1pdV2ueys0efRdsZpBrc8Vif7lMCHmtqURSo/Zlkl8M6pEG5U@X2M6NXxzn66nHVqY/GQjJwlzwX6tZ3XUdKM4n51okHOIC0Smv@xujUcMVicuSK@zvL/q@RHoaSjEdrdKk0iVXsqmqUAsqNyG@yOiBTlE29Hq4Vk1HK8lMMlu4SF93C9Fqjr@@drWucsl0vBbKX/SHgYsWpyeYxGV/UPVRg0Jy2GEMIzKRqlJGT59rqXn/Zng1mrRn4WlBby2VC34i9UZclx8PmwUlHIpfNR6DJdafvmTSN0tZ8YWD8yjVEbqdPCNXhtfNiJTOMi25Dx3oFMj/8PpyogldTe9Hm5Dzy6USTtZLvYaWlftloFBuT8ZCdxSVhn3Rf0NVmGokE27KF12h1KqMwq22dF3L@8PdyRz6r63U8qKbYqDU661qf8Jeh9JgugYCj7lmf3Q1LTb0SjDVqBXKAarxWEl1uVy6UGjcGB2uWGJ7malRD0eyaU4YJYbF9CLRTuRmGaHezLoGLl@tI0wzjbicbnR4fb64YaOsFu8OqNAgdJnopjhjFmx0tUAy3y/5eTmnzkv5yHhUKed9iXz6qqsONTZxFV9dof@3uGvdaiNJ0r@pp0gK20imdMN2TzcCugUIrFlug4TdHExjIZWgbKlKrZIAjc2P3R/7AvsA@3DzIL3xRWTWRRegZ/acmTltSpmRkZGRkZGRt4gP45963rvxdadS2ftQO9u@tip/2975svqhE7ZO/JW7GoNt7Xabf/xpVyHuYOAzmHUbeG2ERQtd7eai/IjjCfY8geftKb8TuOyTdCTQ0e@rJd60Y5/ihfCaVMJnm3mEzMHRYnnybDFXMu4E@A/8eKjX7MCwkzoItQcoHJGx6PmPEcAnnnyCgnMwfp78Mlyj/4gGx6AkNvGLugzzJvskbcwR@PmAq9biRTlx5JkpJakBgdRlTb9D/HTsl/Cq8IoK8hFw9Wg3O@tYv1hOlSfiwr7PnkbsXN7motorBjClUUhvIj3yzWCxQxZzsPZIEMBmofRj8Yef2L@H8p2h0zv/6cJ53dqwlTv0mn4vHA3u2l@vg5vbjuqq/per@9b4778r9e6tgkej1VfiG7X0w0aBnWn/hd18/sT@t18Y16Qc5wCevth7IzyhLisVubkqL6osfzj4Z80uT0mpet0zUihOPnrnP1xs@BvFcu/cvyj7KyvZ4crGcKW0kkHCq1K23B/pm4jnwwt@tV94rQ7M03qEyMHd36CjjgO/dRMsh@q@6rZSb07Yo5kZQL1mPzmebt3WMBgkUzqQp2YvNRCnk3BK3Jwo6QUGbjjuuzi6i7wSdAOSX/yzMPrhbXk6Hy1cWIALjbK@O5FswDerP7rqeq01a4H5iSNwPKdfW9NOYVoKcruwwGmeJAotygszyC6b3FbQH@vCnoBcmrasJ1BuZnC2mnWeA2mgrkgmLxHQcEBgAiLsTYErQs1Ho1mhCt/7rh@dg8KPT7YMLydq0eQZjz@Ah9yw353LofLYSw/9WVcalH1gqKz2OMGp5x4evfFVgs1lyVr4Mur1@fw5L/RqjiBa82W/6Q2ikvlwdIXXvaoEZniGaPQAPh7gEe62OXSTXWP6Ahff@PEV2gN8xxxyiwhuNQeDMXQjHh8AXzvgMgsSDjyjhoFcrBQydFluRlZ3NTEOru6X@8triu/BlSmJj0TLidwvlIu2zsnuUXavObyZk30D3KNwXvaAshEkfE62R9nyJnJ2fkD5ctI/B2CIW54krpfD4HLY9LoZcegBVyAPorAzamXFMDYSASUdI/2RLq@0axS1KL0jwpYSLxqfLFYCAJHO6MGD37G0cC78/GZELhJ1Ck/UN/VkZfpyJLH4kmsitYv6s69T@FWCABp/pErVdL6pXHo7amhKfvI07Vyjt4lZb9T3749RpgUxLX@lCyN90kO4h5tooXArxiMxjON@lUJ/14Vml9GuY5LazdyRiNthBuVqrEJkbMXjuuP5baqDEC8mk3HlKat@jlPOwwu1FmmPmI8yLJ7m4@qU9OBGFI9IR13Fn63nc7UJuaeSTZqRr2JlAT9hzfIUO8MIOpeG3iToiJsTctZKyYwepX@2sc9rzRLRx4OaeVMWRdsi03BTEziDvKb0a1InCLIXy2uSjojLXhqZNweZ@NO7JATDdaIBM5tR42ZO9Py8vEklPV9cfevwFXMBeYjZZJTVc/j0/zC4wDg9ZY8QhDKtktQM1kyBR@0GvzYnh9xE80TTz27cuTxqXv55GTSqaXliqfuZZsk1VVSR46ayenhaD/1znPkWd1/K3gkz83WF6XQjic8RwYc5jH5SyNJNWL1QKY6DBNYMT0xJ7IRw9qQUX62/NCnm2qWM7bkWGKgqp/NBsyA0GWQoJ0s52ubajFWn9r54OTTGjRNbYYj9LFJBJnvZSqpzLOd2efJOpkauo5gjyRy8ZIeFOTCUeR1j25IZbMrlW5foZmEy@Elj@joI2hljMGmDgTEYDx0E5Ig7q8isEvMyrp6q00avutZePsy8W6aURZ3E8wolwPjUsgkiXl/zsClj2CTsGy/k0OScj9mIqjKvD3BZUbSPWptMB3RkAi3MLGQ0PnySsedKred5Jk6pB3u76eNiKIcd4KX1uo30qCMAs0kL7di/JffBw4xdBvHhqb1bfksuXbyyl4dNHHW6uQWZLUfUrK/bqCYS@Ic/lhYLo3BQuPL8guvfklF9NbaWlOtLcMo1NRp2cj/ionDlZO@D1iZ8L5svIZKYUE@htrzv3mUAQ5YzvIjaWUt80vGlxZIFv8R8b7zr3rbJ6hePLf0gvOd/x7RYKOZH/WHAOboi9l2nvnvfY3@qRX5FpFcMmpx1xhPDZPC@QFLHclcyVxIDqQSfy9kEinOUZIVrf7Jt9B8I1fdJzy@sMO82WzcgArL3XZZT1F0syQ9WaLoevtbACjxeoc@ueJno891RVMHWSTjm39R8/C7hQ1L4iivkXq9TLL4QjJxuEPQh5LgKivLrxABh/EK9sVM9OcnrEFZyYx233OUeM54IssM6DtcQXePFbXW4C5ROWUBjgVvq24iRs/5lHqFazSYMhTuwU3gFf4TSglyJf001I4LPCjizhJ876V8heFnUXj36ZEeBd3GxTKJYzhQzwAlWLDzJjWarBUcQB24vIIq33W6XiBZeLMTswCc4YupfieoPz1HnRUS85Oem8nOp/LzkC1ExVL51M4iB1pJA9tK3GO5B2TGYM1XXhqJG1w7Zu1Q@GCToLj8GG@ZpkebFwJtRV4pURhnrqYxcIue3Gb0vOYupMpGAR/nnkq/le1X3fERlCvaXdP34a@kOctkHg36yOCGled/r/izbj1EOa1gFt0pSHP3NYieDUm@IaHWSIzVBQszDdnMjxrJSMhqHx4y9uf6LnddbUj9nJsnI8guBqYE1Y4wkuMR1rjDj7nkmoXo4ezGBgnFC0JQZuZum8FgXHifQAmrRVGsZT6HpAU5NmxziG7jW/R3/mMGeJs7ALc3OXBDK76Xx8tIizSBWuov2bDaltclwMHIlUTfqkVkkrns8iXG2kjgMsAJt3UBTRHW68h6kE4z89mKkJ5KKwmiKKb5HOZrTMUDJiO@8LkTmg/VH4bW11@yRVdh171UFNnWTPfVbqcc2QzcchghoRA0cqHDU73c97ddN3fFzDmlnafUdHiPEGBNGQ96q4YGowDv40o9jqFBeHQHzHd4Zxhnh6PqaKsZO8E1wB9Xa8QjlMG9V/DF7JmY3aKvy5MVVI/hxhQLu0rIvQYT0nIwe3nmAlZa3zMMiaWpHxrc/JBOIGh6wz0O4Wl2zrL@NvNbX7T21Wiz@pVR8U0qwzGxVF/Nv3qpawkQyGavFUrH4rvTWsraD/lieNmZaWeB6mwNCR@1jov9Asuneur7vWhWaMRgwJNM/dAe3bjtvWSdum/eAr0bMEYjyCOzyjZ9XpJBtBX/3ZO72QkfRsusG6gV/MT@L79oWO9ZwLLwh6ruDnjeUl0bBrdcGA827qU7Q7QZ3vBGNJ0vCDxTquUNiyuusSpPEfmk1LWy7sLtY4gZiPrADv6vglv1IazaQnerB/T4/ALLgRBEYkpX57QlKqL5Wt@n1IE4zCICXpZgDhgBqWnvUch@lwWIi/iQNSjesHbRG8MzbND1TIO0X8Fih4e4OPNK@MYO5V7hYgnbq4Mb7Wl3Vj3YbHysnVUXfxydHH2o71R21daYa76tq@@j4jIN4qfdH@6Rd6qpyuEOph42T2tZp44gS7EqdStqcYVUOz1T11@OTar2ujk5U7eB4v0bYCP1J5bBRq9YdVTvc3j@lyXrPUYRBHR411H7toNYgsMaRw7WaYlZcTh3tqoPqyfZ7@lnZqu3XGmdc426tcYjKdqm2ijqunDRq26f7lRN1fHpyfFSvKjTM2qnVt/crtYPqTp7qpzpV9UP1sKHq7yv7@xMNPfp4WD0B8alWblWJysrWfpVr4nbu1E6q2w00KP7aJuYRgfuOqh9Xt2v4qP5apeZUTs4cjbRe/dspAVGm2qkcVPaocVbmCa5Qv2yfnlQPQDRxon66VW/UGqeNqto7OtphXterJx9q29V6WVn7R3Vm2Gm96ihE4OWqCQdxi/Lpe@u0XmO@1Q4bNGecHjdqR4dZ6uSPxBiiskJFd5jBR4fSWmLS0ckZsIIP3AGO@vi@Sukn4ClzqwIu1Ilr240kGFVITGwkm6kOq3v7tb3q4XYV2UdA87FWr2apw2p1ABBO1PuxQpWecqvRT0SXfJKwWkZyHe5OVdtVlZ0PNVCuoUkC6jUtLcy27fea5zSWC9bMI7dHD/CmT/n0VsjjTuK3j3aqZPFJIBg7Tj@lSefH9OFdKo8mmiiTfupTUJ6rLtvu1ej60vM7AZbmUTE5we6F1w7iLGURLPmT9UhATH1QzgWWli4vP1QuaZ1bv7zMOs8pmSLjqRLaC@tjUFndxm7QbPMyP7W3lGTU5ivt690Rx8vJvZZX0eZDVhUKbVcXw@NFIDbbRDooASFrQzPyq8amrxJV8hFzeq@II2ZMbhaZ480gpH/87/EPmRsSCaSc5d5CoYA1LJOByCcqop8q4aAgOjII3wPwOlxlPnTdr9eZYrI6LPn1BlXWlGHYIS0DrzPZJ4pfudcTxXOT5ZlYvDVlY8W4gzdu2iGYAf/SLFO6X/IDbllGtvb4T9ZQwxWRUZiVqvghq759knklxeFfVPYKs@XIlTiHAzmo/Fr7iMVccfVteSL9fZQuYwuvzhHbhua7cy53wX/eXwgADTAPyy9iiTeWI9VCIVGGrDK2JyNg@Kq/AdCd16Y5FVP1jcvTOjzki7vgZHmajAfefZJ6UsN7J5WDrdPdXdKcoPbtj@/@8kPZ0h73B8NfHfl7hno4oie4S1b0nUdmGmclRsk22T27U8FyEtF90HsARARK02mc2CSTNvKcKTaCxNeQbSA0N0SEAR9BNmwECRjYCu/z3UXLyOvMkakFIJNqahat6TXv2cJvkqnEMtASL5ndMffaPf4B7mj4myEeNUgLkBYxt9cfjklyaXHBes/eNQ4HeG3Dz4oBkreNHPeb5g6SMAY6k70w4A0@/9KynehFsmvR0Riv3O1ckohYnKTCBGnhkEtUxXEQmhEsiR6l/KrljT7PdHAgZCHUQ2VYJzbuRiVzJniP7DnrgaExX2xuUBe9ehXVtK6wkZrVRMn@fzp0THI0MClyoUFNIDY3jyI@Rzm8Cf3LclZ9E0mFV2/gKWuJ1b9Jcmc1R2MpG5fo@reJIKMEVxxQhpPuojosA3JmQCJ2ptj0L/GD8f8beTID/zotOAl7zC3Ww54/cp/JScYqvKLVKzPFuzM3xhLX1GJuJpPOYjQPyY65iRqmr@Hdy8ESsUD3ztgknElIscwMBkDIsa@RHL9w4MuD@KZJK6dfeOwuyEn/wG/1@hkTkMtMFVN4Lxy2uRxzRQ4/snKEX1SJ6vYRX@UX9vPIOgMLLtJiV2P1MrQFx0qJdQ4aXXjNmx7RKGfRBBtKZoTH4lTUQ8sM/nt9wyieZdom94FM0fnBvqLjEMQUSil8cwJiFAjffUo2WLON6twEoTPbDU8vvMuv9CyO6JekAnleVg12zxE2O7xmxlSkfWnAaQeqBJ6XbR2z6cod3mG66Ap29iESY1OZl@zGBJXovcjIjDDKN5snrvMkexdRz9uUkNeI@lP/q4/gy65scRmIfCoCVNIFa14dNDkYVPd57bbjylfA1s10/TWf/aq05LwSW3O8cqdasNJ/GcYcIYvzDtYlzUMxl5qtr0i0jYx6dznvnv5wXTndchPTiNYMHLFultH/MHdBAFmZuAOr7E9@tIm0JhPZxktjvuBLxm70dYYvvc@8QY0i4igFF2a1GQSSYTfhkub0aGP6Um51cPl0jSynu7v8VXPUa/qdZs/rjvnW6Zfgxi@E/ijs5/tjy7bt9G4gHIHDRQrRPnTVR89vB3eh2qLhgI2k@uFp/Ti98ZfY@dqWnS@l/kp1qC2u2ZpC34HPpDDoDKlr3LIa6xDxg3i7h/cJ9U4Lb2uNkQDHVAMWIKq3F1nGe4enas/13QHZg8d851Ltey3XJ/VBxhTfwgxvRNMAfBe113Xtahe2C@/slJXr8aZOtLdn6Qo0NgeilaGhSAQPdFhF7M2PSdQTe4L56QbH7WqbTaWboK@9AWHTFMambHF2Rl3HQuzGj7XGeyzGZWHOezM0rZm9PuwliunUk81aasyg6Q/HxBRrcvOGyH5q7yav2BkQYbTms5MXdT0Eb29j268bUlPPqPO0FuAZhIaq690iWBxvwz2nj/ierd42i/lW1v4VHQlfZ1RHqvesuPccxAzNO@rdT6rhQnbVcbfZohWWqo9Q/M0bsgO3gnAI0IOKUsXVUqmUK73BFu1pvZLngYD/TAQxy6odHB@dNIiR2kW@EYxozgTzOWiX3MYiduQQuota/xkK2cCTxlz9zMyDCW78@NplObGw12zq@1YT273UwjBtDvOWLLbkgwEHDoM3KBKh1HCkWuH0ACH6WEmipgR2h0OX6eBjMrVEdLI3Py7wGbR1Sa66OA/9zIU5jRSAe89pVGrAK4O2dntPfdJzexH13tDM7k0BsCZjnkUMk71UEo5lZxlWEnEvm8TTdnFHIkT0gF542xqQbmneksjhCotxiUUyw7opG7WmeeV1PRoDRFfrJsCEI@rKdARvQSQjolnc41GsHUxITMuMaAU0utpBLwIVqiwrcgan0/vhuBWopWtaZmOlFfZdt82REkZ9CQWA/DyN8i7NHOImbi2OEWAtFfne5ICUDUKykO4bdeE7Fr7@rqTPLdMakirjXrBxg2W9IKIW1Yc8SBGxLTNjhe0onPNmudubJBAomwUj5jj6IxR9B4dSRBX1NwsEf7G4OHBH1eX@nvQDiIIcjCjspzOAS0513XSGQY@2688pABHSjYiACReDhhjxkyXfqT2w9A@0F/dO4TQtI22kxo2zETN3PYTQlL2BQF0H@BfAecMxOSN0@YxwynHhPVzyEr5JyNI0JEFFAUQSkKszcOZm4nwzG2dO49SHlTX/lh22oRSLhbRCvEEHpB/BiLj5e4FRvexWrhvIAVPU@utucIW4TaQpqDb8GTtxxyaTeQWWYnQyV5wIpuNNrZsmadL12yZju6h1Gh/uplo3Oxabn3zpKJ2xIWOJfZYpnrt4OPEn/tEjij/tVPAqWB0T0atAnqSS7gZaW6PUKfaaikcmbuIk4XXN6SK9VJHSRBFNXLrIVarIqhV7Kp3oXZSA6sffdMuMXcK3krgH1EbUQUWr17yX1U2RHdDxNg1CRqY84q1eaAEB4HlLRT7tAH5hxS6aU8f2Uof5yVfw@Ma3/cLmkFfFdLyDe3N1j9UAQ6Xyx@wG3M/oBmU1G/hH5P45a4jR7VrnIn5CU0UNlgwr1ewB3mplkrVk19RSvymnhoAKMbElqz5nHuCU3qb/v1YZXUEuSawAwa2uVoXEeHa9fE5LWekWoweLVjwz86@EgqMetER/85UxmQYymdS4Mpo7wimfU7qbUCFd0HFNlvj/DMmuk1TMKAnVUIfBhzCm2shz72l5xmfMjILnn2jHWieKT@NIe2jiz@OaL8yskW7FXOjJqWQWTGJWibjwGLBhdsSnucDzZxtmHfYQoO8EPMG6fWwSa9aZKXg5FJaxleIN2dlp0PJEQ6XZllC6UtaZoYDTXW6IcyZaZSVcmesWTk4jVmrmTAlJJvELYdrVSwlkJ4iyVqoU@D@vw3HdMTmw58KVBE53@zyJiHCZfn9MLCJg0@@PiYUAJ7r9cbEwsQwj1nL5SblI9YSwAJcS9YqB95SSOshk3Ceh7iegmKDxRdKXudvNzKA2oVX1Xqc1ZSpFLNKhS9J18J976Zgl7Wg0JY7EvPOoNy7i1tIc1/rqtiOPzLr10RJp005PCdKbk4EI0GhTA/fRRRYhs6MCpLFlE0yvmXtyd5M92i/LgoXXoIjadX2Tft2bQmtmlWJ22qA03vtj4tdnEp@bjqIQL7HWpuPDR7fLNNW48BQM2oC2rRknvtYTVK0kqEq3LtFDaRbPwZR7FqbcMzAVEpj0wH5D8yV/Lg0Qp859CsWnT9M4@M9vtJDSOEjTtj1sYmMdfNccP4VzkYytJb5T15RbZVGB2E5@CsfPkzg4LuhNdBqnE2@a2HX7uzsIJqNyzOVsWlZmUBRRtTRNlgOyWGvzelfDGVOJ17b5r1c3XrQSWHq6p8WPsS6Mq8Q30SHQUtqrfoQsHv@lOfxzEt2aHg9CeGobhqxl608OhzwYITtM8lQsKpBQZOl1qM5IM@Lx3Enlx6vVSe/HCHg6t1j2yZb8Ihs@iU2nEjVNNFZK4swSLlZOZrYy@m3W8uzJ@pdm1t8P@mTjdGYSwPA97OPLptSESo9N04ml9bPmspnz2XS7knbbRGyS5w/yV1NNX6Wm42E6DWrfvdOz/2OYdVtMD/wTlvy5kZE5RL6cSSQO2pt6c0v5o96VO7CeM9SlRB5/ZI00X3Ita2lJVVq0ZNae8bEr1uLwfa6uEmYwBCFUoz7Oa0K53InBjT0yVwR4ErYd3PkMnbdRBe/R9tymr13l6wnzeoDziwjWQfhOPO7iGjy/RYwO3cT252eJSd12dQ5uJD/C1vLsvodUo05NhRPXpMkSWzMzTq9pJXWOgRNZNQy1NmmoGNnBYehrscy1vUSGeXb2FthzrKfHDCIS4nlV6gXvBOrHZXRtPjNH/YiVUdc8g5WzzK1ol/sZ5tb4uebWv4GTkx1qJb619aAn2LUnldrkIt/6o1CIAjP2Zrhu@dDY3U05PLkam1VBzx28KxaLcIJz1Qz51CLlDQenxF5QSEMXsCde6N/9dfDhqoCiOLRAZII1c5jphkGXVE2YDwbXEo0CNBAooHE0ATnB0cSI5ptEuAfs5/h4lfMlFEjxwNNWfI3Tiy63f2iw8DFKMM9dU5/RQLTvs@qMfNlEv2vKkkFjMffNqDTM0FvbXJMj9iChA4860ZU0RsbrZv1qAQcfG5vfrAU@A5fnghwuPvstfoZov3e73cBRH4NBt71oy@vQdIHd3WSBooDgKqEMnpDDFzvKvfW6iRDOAAFtQdfNd4NrRocTcP1skd8yDdw@TtIymMdO3OvqfT9jn/9mk2BSk1fQzBVlX@B5z7VNU5TNR@hPo5WAGUT2s6B7zX6mxXyaBKY5UL@lir@IojclR9XldjD2U7apybjMkUmBZMUvjPDsaWgwdTa5@S@B52eo6ci28FyOn35z93JL5oBHzLU/3Zc64GFRcGiaEKLneSUeynA69c//D7vb2DnA40be442exCb8jSXbYTbjMbLU7bDToeElO/GbxtWYQceqMlfiWwpgje7Ygfs7YhVkljvhsgRYwVWb@thvpQg5X71w1PJo2PlxmTD8S220zAjUw4/4iWsT/5GjYb074jjesT7jbThcoJjWOyhwiQKW9bK18ftdplKpqBf9lRVVqWzRRy6nKlsVtYOErS21Q7@38PvVxuq7d2W5ObeT/UaJWybxQW0RDp6CVmghsEM/KW8DKyospdDFLwobL5zyi8uN9c1yWDivbF0UCtf09Y///O9//Nf/FCr6x//ixxb/OP8tAsrn84UXrW8vXj2U8ft852L5xdX5i/7F8nUZUvZ/)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001861 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 7766 bytes)

## Explanation

I am using [this](http://joshgit.github.io/) TinCan interpreter.

TinCan was a rather easy language to add because it has very strict requirements for what is considered code.  To be parsed by an interpreter a line of code needs to

- Be exactly 40 characters long
- Start and end with `#`

Since no existing line of the code fits the requirements all we have to do is add the code in an opportune spot.

The relevant code is

```
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
```

This outputs 49, 54, 48, or `1`, `6`,`0`.

### DOBELA (and Retina)

DOBELA has an issue with the commas in each line, the generate "zeros" that are moving left.  Its really hard to put a `_` in between the `,`s and the `#`s so I have to let the zeros get deflected.
However since they all get deflected downwards we can put a `_` in place on the next line in order to catch all of them.
This also adds an additional line to satisfy Retina.

### S.I.L.O.S.

I'm not sure why but S.I.L.O.S. had an issue with the newly introduced `_` so I added a `#` to the beginning of the line which seems to satisfy it.

### *99*

*99* was by far the most interesting language to fix in the polyglot.
The `9` in `49` was causing it an issue.  This added a

```
9
```

To the *99* program which caused it to print `1` when it shouldn't have.
Since I TinCan is pretty flexible about space placement I was able to add new spaces where I wanted but I was still going to need to add another 9.

I tried using a variable name that involved a `9` for TinCan, and found that the variable `A9` and `A` are the same thing.  I assume this is some sort of unintended behavior but I am perfectly willing to use it.

Now we can get the line

```
 9 9
```

Which seems allows the *99* code to work as intended.
Our TinCan code is now:

```
# -49, A9,-1                           #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#                                     _
```

### Incident

Amazingly

```
#
```

Was already an incident token so I accidentally detokenized it when I fixed *99*.  I thought this would require quite a bit of work to fix however with a little fiddling around I found that TinCan allows a space between the negative sign and the digits in its numbers, meaning

```
#- 49, A9,-1                           #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#                                     _
```

revives our token.

### perl6

Perl6 seems to be broken in the driver but it works elsewhere, not sure why.

Comment: perl6 is broken in the driver because it is no longer on TIO's path. Dennis installed a newer version that isn't part of an OS package.

Answer (score 7):

## 161. [2L](http://esolangs.org/wiki/2L), 7775 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x        xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`============================================================                                                x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈ +-------+ 
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/| 
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/| 
♈|       |
♈+-------+---  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#                                     _
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B    =   D  x   xxx x
` `    =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B =   D  ~   8 =  > xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 8=,x  x

# + 
#+
#  +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --ss
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"5""6027""ing"ye re h  do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*
More 91 of thiset of re red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp neeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rc@vKlhj2@cD5B/mCTekekuIDAN@URO3Np0iKIik@9Tw6IAiQIEGAAsDnPjo1TlLXnhlXYl@PXeMZ2/fesVOZqviDy0mq7LKrUhV/dflHHH@cSuX@g5u1GuBLorT3mYmrAolAo3v16tWrV69e/USHN/q///0BXnRVUxY9RTNpUzRMuqvLU1H306kF/YmXjXAgSFEIldR7k5GomsYxdUBzNC2rgtyFd9rUhqIqL0Ud/AM0Pda1ns6PaLPPm7RoCPxYNGhtYo4nJq1J@6MFaTo70gayD2OOZLUHYKaoj3XRJOEhmm6qCj/qdPkXIeEXCY51CDfojKj8MPrBpAVtNOLVrgGQEZrOVFLZUvIFhihNX2q6ISIeQTQMDT1jND3PisIL0DiA8rqslZLl8xdBHEufA@n8WBHnNN8xTJ0XTFlTMYij6@VmvfoyRoBuNXK5l75B@sKnqXRuIgx3gkgZVHWtOxGQP2ZfhGDkqSQrokEJkPczemyXpB8d9AGti3zXAqMkTacxCj0aKrRMC@Mx3VH4vl@gFRlgc2yMFrEI6CWEK32Dno9HtCGPAIuhjcRtWgxaFcUubYxFQZZkgVBAi3NTVA3IseGnZaB9JisK3RUViLAhS/ACMnpibHlZRPiprkbRcAnjF5lYvx2KAKOKK0aIYygJZISGBQdcWfFjpvPjMRAJzKwD4aY8AvmTTadBi7who4RDFENUu4SH47XsazSvbueSnso8zQO9E53gNkQdC9RP8NJ9URcBJb@WPtdMl01gAbI4SVdFXqcbuii6d@vBTpKQmIYpmJgRPynC01NntpJzQlFaMfz82KQO9GDjqkjxtD9BHz6ewC/hcJxQ2XKG/nx4j25L7KG4x7qLd9OJH2mDub8X4TfnOkxPf6YAKwVcUWhGG5sM7xsDgT4TCGR4dKLLNw34x8pWwvTpi7LYEjALqgulQRdUuuUlORMmuo5Ve8NUfgiZVjS1B/yEzOoTFfmh0hEWikDQoGZ6aXEKXAORJ2WkzQiHG30ZCs3AItmqTJaCIgwFFQWyZ3N0la6hKRMCBzENEwUQuAJREWNBolu0xMsKRoFwRGVRrYvGRDExzkTtYsmDAhK7fnpFhqB1EWikTSE5HpASD6hPo61aSIgCYCgIjWQVg376@3/e7fUAT1IQNL1ri2uL7moCUaU8IRb0E40Cq6m8QsgCOC@mbkWHBKa8Ind5E5NXF3YShAiS6kybKF1agwT1mQxVq89PoTpKkiiYoiXklvb10iN@aOkO2ZJcyPiI70DBkgRI2iTbPvpTGkpJEKkDIjO@0cSUYrRvnKWdBvOd6@Ox6@OHexGIc/vdR4cM0zsBgfMfES94c74nOa3kjnY0TN7Q5C41Xph9TQ3QPoF2CAltLKou5w4Op9epd5xuP@o0l/tETgh@SVa7LucpyOIZJOx0nwgJ4U4@fjh5EX07SUAzQzRYXUWX4HZQoHJIpZgyI15W/eMF3fLZrq0wzXhElmOwf8sbGfPSb2p5HJDWB@VSQwEBPeQ3FFEcu1g/50Y1gXB7840B@3L6Aoed4WP5weM8cHq2s04wQE53MoqVtSFrqLaUcR8bGGCKaoxBfesouwIP0mOgFjfBBPDSHSLXRPWDZiE6cSY6dZHugCJdyRGpklaVw/g@VJQ2hk0VWsHt1mixu1WhQRlAnTaNV1pZ0WaQMKEN2zBQISomzvegiCCylaGklSErReKzm7WhCooFsXVEOubryFAZsNqBbrdlfyuPAB4MWDCAzaosWzpoxC8Ai2C1iZuKQ8sS1KkRqAl9QQsi6h5QQqLVsGAiE1IPDTB@0AxifYFweLeuvapqps4kfbegrJfMuzUKM79dqVDh0JI4oxVe7U34HtpfKkThBUEcm7bCgpwYJqikl@0O8fTZjajf6FOHn16mTRoTu3ndSgOVvVV6dpPIo5axLTCfAkqV5m0bku7KOqgnZfEydQCYvkjc8T2C7BDwveMNElaWAAiZOBeFiQnaDQR51peFPsguUqda@tFqjF4mD17bqYOG90nrpJEY7uzbAOVn1l5IxpsofFiir/FAI4uoznY8SOFve7yPmTdGexBraxKhQdjy9TO8H2TvCzhHmqrtQQqMXKNFkN0QqxzAIqujNQgN2Mr8IpV1bSKuiwjKDLQH1HyQv75pjo1jaC9ksz/p@EFSmIa@KJgVFYWFMfWFbGqWu6NoHVDPBtRPZpUCI0w68vxFhojfugwHBjUFQ0wy6AS04E8TkDqXUzJAcRL/NAJvBTmIAicorLsDAAmQHxjlkgyiknOgVOoLVXA5/KQq@aHSOby0Ayuuww0OjLXmS1oboRai28RAQIsvpYPmkkBb2bqfqH5@b5O3bgOIfed0@gearLo@Oz98@OA8dp6Bhv/w4SO4TtH1EV0ecH0kLh9xIZwfXSSGl7gw9I7EQL8H5/PdCvPc/YDFNsfWaSmPXfzd8XHwwcvfcfYzgE83qDrQbADtwwfgcboTCXS63Y6zGWTU35F2c59G7VwXdHlsM6HIT3nr3eZCkLBBHo01HQ3ZE2xs3@fJKKFDawjGq9B36c77O/b@4f7zfddz/@z0Ymz3CZ/oQKYgPdfI39O1CTSb7rvQsY97cLvvgtBYdhJO1nnkcsV8CiTEu92/iLk9vMVtl1MEre26v3cCU23@3Al9neCbewNu95pVQAc20GAbupz@zzFIv@N@cHucENft9EJXI@F0AmcEZIJBMo2SSRiUAwFM10s7Xb3RENQjLRgK2hQ@3TIr4JU5sjy75LE2nY7pAmlZVWgvgQRoLrvrLo6qqT51QgxhYqVq2wmRzhhCED9sPFAxyjswiFiS52DpQ8VdrCwabIDRqElDd09TRH@b2BgOGiSfxvrq32vWVK12wS8Ym0IEAwacY4UXoGbuort30PeAEASVYfaHuE9eIX5p85DuyZfyCC2DwKvIv65MzO@JbPSRvWAiYZ9Al4CraHtD4y4SrhVoARrtHnBanMumZYyDINQxSp43XG40/5KW@YRWGzb5SNSq607aY02AjosITT@GWr1AOqtOZV1Tkcn@LKAGiT3BMniBfB97QYySyUIg8zZ/9yEHjr3y5rZ4u431JXMFQ6AZVVO0nkYfAQCKpt9vCzZUjkZ/IlKi0Ndoxz00IYEzmumKUwYF0gG6ug@2kA/sDVEnre06mj14Q5naBJrtrqjII9kskFEMRcW2aaN3V6FpKIANgqosmpRtUG6aKxzQ2KgStWfBZ@eocQxKJE@6XMlkH6vJRj7hYCaGzihyB3LYFR9HYFkoouGg6QO6JkJsO8JyqNQ0zUyQSopjJ6@vAwRawZcyj6VCqpas3VjJkHiGPJooPCZmwdfJu0VgYXvgRdK10dqKMmzeHgaRm@LOABp2LezQEIZO7OGzLf8o@o9w6MsvUD1BoH2a9br2tAFjCIjDYX5hPKZ6Hg9CkuGxtacNGScocYjMr3dWnp859hn91@NjW7bqNsZ94W9HWiPnCHJDnRjjrcx95gLEf2pKEirbtXeQeA99gAasLMLhPcOCNngEYbtaR1TmkZBPVCS/OV/60YCJhCjrQfu6b0HsiUvNl/siUCZYI7659CKA1ymLwgaojJIG6qEkG2QUdVsoqHU7dE85Vo3pTpvp2IQENp1b2jfd3yt3bCMi8gkSNdTQhtu4HqEHGkYsaxSjofI6pgSalNx2QF8R9TrEqhejjkRuewCO7Y4eVHIcdkSuFHHQCvuaGrRr4oyAEZOVIANuySrP1MgDjdd99Oya4TvEdERpAiqfAZsC3V8A88VjBFLqdOS3QIEvSPrquQdMn3T2sQ3kq/@qp0bvMN6c6KYidu3nf/qDLhTA6@Lp8wvSzK0dj8A3IhvSm6VlR8UXcttfsgRmMFFknrCBuL6EUuBxkIxX1o79qFEf0z5fn9ehcBerwgXhxBtU9nfkzKJcF5VJV1w99ydCWLzbH7Riq/KI5AieaA4R8/aN6C96s1Z8YlAoGt8lWKxmXxY3pW2Vizjne5A5ZkspgUr9CjpXnU56M9oLvStzYt1xgPdL5SqP8befK8e7QsaG@Q4nMprBd2TxHTnQ@eGkq/nGwx7JNJIWeUvarUqEfSSfpPBDy/mIzv0MsLKoy70e9A3t51tgsz6YLsYYjCFmRh7viMqqRaFJy8@/h1NXrPtbIKs5r7XjbT7JCrn9HIEkIiJArUHW4tSLb4tN8gvGKnxngb2b/s@XLEyQNNWgeBKCx8MGsdVeD9VtJnnG47fjo5lB4sfj@2Nb80EEgaBJkih@qTZDiySPeMUX6G4531TOq773xrUHdACdUzCtFd4AITFtNotTKBZye09wsZERUFw2rnfEdkPOakT2rUG9TZyxLGiKbIytmmS/vKUlXw6HbNDgrB@5baLi22v@dqEjgQ24b@3aX9E1wcSBtTfk6CsUlzWmhaOGW4Lh197inaDN8Pem6dDXpqJ139@YLfdS9RUqyKcQyZCFPdG7wpfEFadoyG0/F4d7qTIFZa//MX2paXpfVA064GdXgwA4Ls4rijXI1ihU3pZpQ1Y0A3obeH@PF9CrMAzrvl@at9km86qPDHVsu/dH20sUafjoJLm/Ubi80tOUSKzH8HB7UwImuoSa3n5@rYZbayiO@6KGWhtCmsrZzzdV@xD@vyQcZHhFx3HULec77eo@dWaPv72dQegu4OTI/szl2BiJ6WesruBbBaAL/Rm/WD3/Gq3HW9xdtR7jBTGjwc7DCPEYOEzdMq3/OqmF3k@t@3U66hXa6JcysVW4Q0UEjU3ur4qUDrDcz4zBsezXayxJmYgTca8GqXQGIq41eUd3fD1RrJ2NQ3tYhAHm4aDIGmppdxK/impsz/HtXYXDKzJU8i9aM3tVzRhs7zH2q6vgqKLjdcSeOhnvFO4W72oTtfY@5/rjVc3WujtEYsjP1UixL9tMO@a5IZLfW6Z8dqRBV1gbgQ2hfkX520jJOJN130FMfDaYBzKOyenv4j2m1xMuYL@CPQKlKg8NHw7sfZ3iCbzVhyfA8Tj00lTRXOD9LW7vU6QdTVN@TumAPu3KaKaB8Ykrq75USq9sH3vujd6MVhg48tGR3hqnsNoau0MJ3MPO85sFXYUsmaRx@JpSfjWQ@E6rtTWs@KV@JbTYZDDI0IWV@y16a1i5OX/MH32X4NVgGbNyvIcs7g9@jX00Xhm9ZFgZh6KtwefNZMHBC/0zXgCn5K7PEPriSCSv71j8fHcwMVaPN4HmGv72BPsZMu76RryxDBVexfvOQPeWSWRqqmgwJq/3ROyrKCIP1qjl@5aSXQ3n7mVuYcT3xNwXJWszFIGrMsgM2JZz/6DEsTVRKkC0L6gRqxuoqUNxYaye@43lhQDlORm9i21fJRdwxPOLtdrP7B3C/oLNp/a1vtoX@zqpGeu3t@oGSKRprTJ9LxNAf583hrgMhSikTR@vb2xzV9EU5Wu4iwrRUo@atn8wNovrP7sQ9WfhXfAdCLAfXxy3g3abMIk04G/Vnb44gebJ0ExtLPrI21ugCo7wWPf948uFitOg27Kod60pOBzu4025o4j0TAYSBsb2pMH@0aOOovG40ukdCx44s3p@zXiUoOlfahJ6vGaOx@TxOFYmBrmRYV2ftH@88pjOEUK/RhZk05r8tCRW7GkdoS9/qfA6Im@q8pCxa7/9ul/Kd3UxybhM@zLo7VdkYJW@8KMMJLbD6/go7K/3csleO/6uMZKe6Priy7phd9pyPcRqTQyg463BGHsuak8wafZxhn81k/3O7IQ9dfWmQBFDGo1mn8iCZcK9OTS0sxrBZoESDJpf4JKgCcMv2hJvDlbaM53IKkHemo8F/5cjGu@TkbfVG/QMXflJz3B/CX6BdlZGHlmr1Hllsw7nCzGTvS9KTkNW07z6BaBA6T0Aa6KvRhZIr5fQGV57ZTf4ybq9jtdYL5Y/KKiCLpIFdasFVvQBLvObIJNNTffTBM7l4j0et5uyIuHYVU8FsBUUWa6MSxitldAGrciGSWBlib67ow8/z4/ZY@6ZTtCOYwf98GBhJYvpsvMxWWdcs6LeHfIPiUOnz@c8dN6rxzTrJKCiYoj7QfkdOEkmD4vOTdZplbeWUKB7ldMTa2mm0SfLn0EhdUGxNcEWJsKt6dYCQ2sVawMnwf7jX3btVeFg/Bj0SDag69hTcSeDNhL72uyjla6denI85nFVOeKY9VFrYuq@dJI2ZqgBrcXg2oxu5hoxe2mpvd8CXqpYVbeosAoVzXBcV2JahWZR09VESyzshNexVpkSNGUyUqHJ6Zp9w0/XZbJkZKJvFgKAC8FUU8d2t@ulC3RXxKkGshKImJqKpg3Jmjyk5D/@pbWglqwHAhFC9yp5sqB@K0Vc9sORVayCoE2A6hWSpahrNogLmQzmzgR7cSDUouXvxlUyZKUvSKJvtc4Vk7HWuqaTddqXpZ24IQRXz53IkuswWTtv3bEPiR/pESP@pz9g3J9tvjl@4YtGDIeXXoGcPKNcbQeHIXgT6qQdh3OHnS3cekBW2q@Fyt6T5EI3Ka7VutUR2bVA5E6ckXWrZC2JitYcbgcABWKAsWO6CWqr0iQOXROry@Crm3QYd82AFc6Dy9rnQFYB4RpMjHI4p3@g@ygrPoHmwiy8WQxRcNnvKJFaTSEHtyf6mYzYmZDZrWnAHwgmSHYOHxOnZ8Sli10Nl@HffXc/D7C@@3k0@8AYK@bc389/wQaugXsaWDOH3zJYgbLlzOdD/xn7ww8Gv6AdjmfnibXwAWr54edqoZqtN5KNZh24@Wxl9iCn6SN@oylQFsjior6mkP0NwBZdFo0va4@1Blm/AbjLRR/y9CnupnK7qe01NATUZrXD5zi0nGsQMOu3Y38h@r74hrgV/hrA1kySTNtalK4SQbJlxmlsa1DvSrawXLC6g/G15giuQtmjCgmPHHQCuOQDLn0lj@jXubRK8CPxgGL8MqPex7EPBfBqA/EaAJm0Tgvza4Vbmdub@ef/D3I8hnbtb5pjguPdHCPEezkGwE00EiOXLJSatexuJBCnzWY26DrpuK9RInXL2hZjSZdm78BYaSbS6zDsldZr3WrQU9kgvRKUNwlbBujYk@pIJrkN1C7Wukw6qRigybtdUE2dhYmaDVS6n6x3shY9@VTacQDM8q8bWi/toBDWSLxeiQ@aayaAFvveinxI4Ahmg9qzdeheZH76@39ubRe6N8H9h7Z7zqbg7Y/tNwncf28VwnHw9g/WbwF4@5X19h2DrHy9N8LKzZqJyMBWoUobpOOELBrx863cY9uGbaesgukuj4DXU8I6BLeyteHMBo/rrgWch@ICtqOSRr1M0hP1BxeubD9mGDRFcKjLT5bWiHOr20QWuj9NcKMXNCVMJBwJcdBvEH3TFUKyWLWHazkshG73MUglNZXHie87An16eko7DIFXxETkxGI5c8h/F3R8vyb0EGApy2q5oyEORNnEgLAzO5rrkPdwboyKldPJOemHEzBIrBKENs1FHADiRm91tZoTGk3NZhWIhyrOTaL4FytrDEwhlSwmFK3tfitEPkBk4cbtSC@lfLM6Axezbcm9f7sYHG0EqyPYsWOfkN19R9@b9@qDvS2NBoH5zR6RU8H9R3v2qq2lJ/l6k5Tr5RYnzA39qa5quIonB9TSrgATCDJcxL1Vpxw2KqAXa9APgBLqDNRBQZQH2thIprOFYqVaf7XJh0A6X4I5aefZqefe5/fePawdzhdSv2JqKsfUL1O5FSu3qdoMeiPEZuT7JZn7UntJ6Rupt61lMa/TJgGvEuLYr0VMOm@@HJkceo19E8psAaataftXqbrcn5/vHk7P7tWDV8n/sG8D5IH/CIULXPcG2f7opPfonMJqsU8Dd7ob/tWi0oBjs713vfDWet94v71NZ71vfrNXZ7WsiCKLrNdrrCn/GwuOIO9@xkqKbFSxCFvRC7pmRSqHpG4SFKhXExfb1NB2Xl5v8bfXEq@ZVLE6smQfIq9CH0aXBQvaIAra6u6STXPQ4SmYmz4S9Luww066ggvS7QFVsR4y6MpkyJXXV@uA1yF1cST7Git6UHFs9t7Ym076kDdF7pzwibs5vV5T@94WFL8xVmTThfth5n7sTkJuXG7MAHeKG0rm7tP4g713h15tsfGQXTrVCfCrqo3pTRc@I65cNejF0ZkJIAcxEOniZARwEnnURGwlRLqs@SAy8NG5IuIO96XYefCPumFI3d8X5125By2Ny@0FlfQLjtvs7@Fxg4rqBD1sseocV3dsM@Zn7Una4hh/x/tltSvOXbhd4PgBuQP@zll76nQ7XskA2Rhl7xPqvtwhtVIWvGnX2s3uohcKIR5fK4LduhOP@/sGhWueoQcCKdZNvQROaENd0ogf064J2WJm0H6avLruXarXMHU37TvD9mxGq7THQ/ou8CABfprElIhLVnDU1IU7s11MAsoZfQ21i4@lPKbvOL//AdwkETd9iKMPaTA3sN/upsA0hSjHBC00wPB3jBTNoJeGFFnPQ5IsRTaJANTeYFKRe31SAYEXJNf02bebHRdbNdDiajx@bJfGrjqM0yAWp3s0BqDdo@ZWtinw1161ClxDJQZQaeiUyqBQPl2Iqgr11QUyM4LaSfMTEDLd7V0dMeLd7DgnKRxYJObtZbBA6O5O9Kzzs6KBPXPInJAe8MkztPvf32PDL9lN/4L5bxk/c/LZdagkFgwYY@4z12E/wXmCRx7PoXrkOlTRHPn2W@w4Px@CtfPod/gdcwDyHSruE5BnsI4Sh@rJIX/qOuwmAkckBrx6PO7PEOFHg/F/PuSfmcNvwZrwgo9u1U7XoUE2h7F@P/cM9GENOWS8IDOfcZMUOSAEkz@UPR6kwX/4iAT8yNzXPaRdua8zpI9@Yhu5TG@0UiO7tsq6JF4deGIx0PY@Xmv0MNnRYM1qPq6At/eh7wl717q@wIUgNBm3Fg1jW752Q75esdgKDZWTrWRc1u48YODcBUzEVy/vdoMy@f3vD7gI9Po@RoIuzfMxzJ54nGHuxHlAH3xyMEcO3fH5PuOb0qLPeSfxYf/TQ3VYrV677110nHYepCsOLuT4jo4HjhjqgDlif4gyzPfffw/mMH135j/zP7jvfM6HO5fVoYvSZ9HokTcSO/J@cj5uepBR2u0KBNxQaPd0mL6P8vyRJxT4pJ5ASByvIM2BE@8x@HF0OExn8frP//t//tP//Cfk70/J79/Lsjw2ul34aX16SC/hGko0/hP3srvl5tHdkZYu6GeA@ZkgVYOrOp3hoLP@HW4D/fgB/sg/XOtXvH8gPrY3AXl9faAOzoSD5QHHcQcL8veIbm6@yvd8PvfN370Yjgvc4zb3YOTDJxq4KnrIdXz8acM@xhGNOTSN@PQhhTCtHdDdylYXfe7DizpYHajASw0e/@hGB/9qJv61hq2hrzWsCfiXGuLfZQf/Skv826IqlvDSQNSPiYTn3Yve4@f3P65ciOP70@8Tf4OL/pnXnDqArtzB2dnD87PHd@f/znNyYv@DEjxZv@FluYDeh2ef7/S7M4/njtB9d2Zn4NT3cGblhtz9j9@dPnh8ntO701P/49nZ/Mz38N3ZHebyM97mz3gPOKBe3R@hMzE/rVkYMyuUKOw0/pGrZCVyVy1B16XhDZz6DgK5ZNobqDdTBxy8hTevGBjE11o2mak0Abpayibr2fNCK9usgr/x8Hj26ZPHD4LwCeg9e7gDkn7hOfMkTNN8vH088mOrF7cav/iahhfX4x6X9UodZM7mTcZ3CkSXHuOYwRpJzQfMePiBttBSB3cHdy7PR89HVmGnLDfkhpdaZfNfqcwhQJ6zA01n@2yf60KFoVmxyS7YxZwdaRWuC04R/tgROGVWmocqkcqnOdtjVVbluB10b/@PKtplRQOEGkQz56yJuFkJnr1K5RKQSZD8AP5klmXnQOecncI/q3Dk@u6RhUy7IYyFN5a9v6fuaMf3Iig/P@f0s05/xOmUH8KR8dPn50Dk6Y7YauH4wx1ueH1w0F7n4/2d8@HkgDHu7xlLTzsCIccJ2RH7/Pz4mEk2ko@PDA5xzU8PPZ88vk9wJc48p/bj40H37OTj/bEPxW8liAfM6cf7s6AP3REPcD8AfqeM52deG5Tw/HBPOV2zdruNv/ZsOrNcxGH53bfXoXhrM@BludALLgRl9sXfdcxfS5zLdRd@@PwMzdW988RpN2gummwud3D384BEBxzYaXDF3WAzcEG0TCNh2n12FgmDRyTm9rlY7FRYUe4d4/H43uEnwyh@sqAxkUjqOr/ArpMrBEhc8XAice/g9cd7x13gAeOGffEIrem@eNDtcLu/405PIQ1MIuAGb4dz7tB0J/35efvP9fn51EUuN/653ejpBqkhzzO3CwDcYXibf3bRp65TF/qBF8b7/HyGTgL3GVx3LveD@/nZ8oO7y31qYT1zA@NosBf@K/1DO/L/n//LJm2A2fF8gIawSofCbldnIbpDEVfME7f/Eh@AsS5H0BlEC8fJO@/uPh0Fj6Khu48PR/4j/LlO788e9rS2brB7oCKvql6CO8CCRU3mP6k5uIDDie6DgxPB3k6vaD06GD/BBhojOuBCF@WkoUDPTtcivGl/3GdY/jQpUdr9QLufP4NYW4FgLLvs@ab7@zmLCoZ20yedxOHnA/755ABToJ8dK3C7dhD8LucJmZB0fHYc8vod9@B4dhx@7jxjr@KIcxODMhw6OTkKWe5oDNzckdsaYwez72TthhDR4IUTVEMnByi9TmCk@@CeSnTEHuCD3I63K6gnHA5/YALwmP8ikg3Mj@zr7GjPFQvEPEeeT3dH8TiWxwPx/OEDdYLTfdbcosPnsGo5HYsTKg5wYgKvU/GwCkaF/XeUObJcHP6yHwwKesQdWoUeZ5Slu5qCm840Sfpg@UPXnu6IIvSuREVZHcAAHUClO5O74gfKEOEaVXlxIoqzyWQmrq@0bBzzgwE/Jtdc@uk3v/zpN//DT7/91U@//eVPv/3T3/36T38Jv7@E36@s56/@VTyM99/9@h/8zz/989@C57@H37@D37/93a//yR9YP/L@H@D3f275/Qf7twVn/SjA9ce/@/Wf/MXvfv33/gx@/8z@/dnL30//@N9Y//@X/YfO3/70j/8D3uyXX/4KCvGv/vVv8P9P/vVf/bvf4P//8i/@6l//o7/6439JHH9uOf7vf/avrPt/@du//C//3T/8L3/712/cf/nu/ddf4f/r/wo@X0/n1@D5mnz9XJ9f/7Xo@ZtwY5MKyABI2h/99E/@LsjqP7be/g68wT/t8VmXZwXzh@j7wyFaO/T9D9ugPzBg/rA0s@X5h/QP97iVgdtAQhL/9AeGBVOOZX7YRboN@ke/@/U//Avw/eETDX4r0L@7QmBrnB3QNanwW2fiDwH8n9sZtOD@8Kff/MFPf/Hf//SbP//pN3@MOswXinuTXh/3fofhAADDXwGHgJGvgUPAr@qqPFIWqg/0BypAnnizPekPxDU/osJB0MArN7dxB0PEHYb7Puw48/zx046XhftoHzAB/EjCP@wlFtM4ot7K@0cS7eM6Q3sAPkEwtJekyTzFO76ATwq6eHZPL3EWoxOUl44l6DM6hYAJeCfh6CTv0Lri2bMJKrOCoOkM8MPqbEP373vsRFv@ZxYofUbRPxJoG03CQvQjBZ52/B8J2gTGmc8pgg3/bWsV3fhbBaxu5JWyPeZzu8v/0oOCDHlJdBAMqG8HHhQQD@XBhVRYGh58eo7Iuomjn3t5CFLasy10nq/sLGPCFjA0tpsp/228NtzBNlZCrxXBQ2A3aWMQdaMdHyd@5EJRCp7kfYLHB0G7TA6em5OzYf3QTT9F6LPPPpQH6qyebUBYo0JzAdZP37EPn0PRQCgcCgeCkUg4GuBCkXgoEo4FWY6NsOFAgIuHQvFYPPpMnV3Tcz9drV75ngHR3OdjAoiRTnDh6MkiATGJF3WGo9wJy/ZYfPaB2YEU3BOz5zNORmMP/rMPC@4buGjqG4r@Brzg8j1T1gk3QOMMM0AmPmh7aqRQObEH0PEcNGsQ3cGF444XHHfjdj2DuhfVrpUeFaWbVbjVCuf5xtazkU2m81SETlXKmRePsA0UpkvZXGP9GrVCV1HDaxQ32VLp5av9QJvsAx2Oer1@vx9u@PSSizz9h9@tQDj/2/rOEXY4Imwg6nCA1eVY4Dohuk@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@JwzAk0LwwdjseVP6QD9OTzfN/sij3rWujWU4CgAgTJ80k21zk/7/R6HX2RzJ7XSFCxmOcHi4ne6XXsiJ1HuDSMBUHD0eLlJWLQ4yOv7A@6gCD1RdDj4lEkFD7yT0CZffUwodFjEYOKELRvjNxGCNcIgDt4pUbwTPEdK2h1kSDynHc6jhMUWaw6kosILu8lD3KCGPTQcarTcPEfiWo6NuSlqEku1juJuX3hj5OYIxJ1HB/B0/HREQQnVA2adUKX3eG8dzjcd/GHj45o2HHs/PjR5/yW@0g7onHHsSMaBZXvPnnG1sDl/iy55t55ggUPhjnFCo1VEJ7rpshuKQIxB@hK8F4BWDV/XXeh2QANTcPP56MwfJywKXbQLjzqD5cMk/kvl9MZDTidbucJxP3gAFpsUsiqYszyimIH6AygOB6A6LpoTnSVZk@eX6WsD48Nk9dxApSkcEw7ItCugTeen/j6@gQmsvf4qBM@Pftbr67/5m/tu/b74kVZbXWEow6eqS6e4xGKn1AHn6nnz8@nZ6skL@jFgvf4Vq/f0nTPc0gdOjHnzuDukGMykezVkqsRlmQazP@gFtIODg8PqYPTxpkj6Kj4H9fjqWcMGaK/x/F7HOv23z@efvD8tQZbff6zT6vZCSCdoXQRlwN38Xx6a9AzFsaS6NHGgeeveUEiVAJwUic4UuU4wOojKNoEJ5DoeytDpz8ekEFRuvpZmqhkPcjxJRovLv64Tk5bunsAGf6xLCufY0HfGZnGdIEIPxOpECpkiok6UDXbCXzUJqYpzk0X2DxhtHncUF7jevy76Hex7y6blWYl94k9jh3HCNPv721B8XJOzkmK8fETNFZyLQuW5A9amPtRLZ4cHI@dwZAzuC65@8SBxSYu6j44C0T9Br84eLB3QbhC4PlgzYoHuIP27jXbeZmSyRjqIHb5/Q9k0Mk6Hl0OEBfD0PTh8@kz/J89352ePp/iekJ44L91e362wsk/krZ6IY/NtQO3gdmE//UEyf948PCj79T6P8VbumIxwREJO9wH3yfOoHiN7x6/e4S@aJx2BEiZeBhrfGuMX6fA60glf6JxhH/fbTyOIPbR@k08PTLo8Bn07cCPYZh791UArJF4PBKLHFC/B369s6QLQtdrHCRR1I3JaN8ih6QuX/K4AERdL3QAx@VkiYewflodgb8yXGi0XHAVD5ou2362NbPlRb4cseu3MBhcco6@FIUumXzGhJZQo7pw5NckS4fpI9wKiDtr3NRn6hvANRFMslodbicU9Q0um8ZX1wrOS39rmG7srrJu6ptvbKVqmH7DfETkGMn29HEn1DOF7OG7XYMmR9DihIW1HYfHRcja2NowryxoK5JBIxLLCiM7aTDdLYKPaMmiAnJzRJMUCeWYOSv5byywzkRCUnKFUhbiQKdFIssN7NgOvYMHNJPsfZDc9LptAB4AFgQnnCLgCAjowNNqZN0j3PMjuAikh@YwXCLLFgDKS3NeQomXluyId/j6ANERvQSqygDEVuouKwf00aOdrJ0Hmx6SCWAh5o40cejg9Z7gtUsPD5e7e3DTn1c7C1wYSp/Sgc3WBxsXFIb1cRUSURh17cNmExs2E2zcgxeK9sRaoe5aw9k@G0Y9U0emd3RiFdX4hLpwCWALaLrr5MfRt98K343vRg8n7lHCxKfHM4Jmd@iSLZAjMzFKgHiM7@SHE/PO45EfEiP3hQvf8UxnbKNti8Zw23mDnKsJoAWXgRhu7/JO9f2oPnhzd6oHSJ54j24TSy@fYNEW8coJzqt4nxKcnQ9I00wsPeoJfwo/XLqzs/ofLA0Pf7LjhVGGLiWxvOMf0LhRIKLHk4PMAJ3GneLxPLghcQUCX0c8Ub79lvcoZ/MTxedzI9R3wY@5OxMcD54Evh@7@NP5x@XdBOIfu@CZgGQUNxAP8WxeP69pB/pOgMdWmW5It2gkttccyBslEke3H49ujxIfPizv5r7Rg9di/zG7kQYkfo7En2ztrnAd3brpFywhczguxy/k41/4QTk6vLLHA0z2jrdiWhQe3ULI2ONZUf2M@pJ88mG1LAwlzN4RYJ1eS46tJKs8yUHCBjmr2uzi3iiImzQEWbbBrU1tYxk6wTxuB/WSg5x5AoFh9jdoMPB@/vEjtUraXoQOKaNy6Yg0j51p8gUCHSeUyPeMrJ2vX9Kv@9TwSueue5H1wm2Whv5qMLJVXYlqIhXO0IU7BEE18Jl9PrE0lrX1AJQN0R4AQ7QHwvlQiyCTbD1hQybsQCitVQFBLNQTkrVrG089NVA/ob28rvmgQiwyoDLvIUP2DhJEN4E8yeCi5VOSHjigqlDfQCaQBsyD/ECfgSKjv/2Wtl9PEzQXiGJbgGAIN/BwCPSKUkj8KygFHEjlAGQU9SFJBGj7BkNwa81OQqG/WUL2zjgXRPAMvNYGOT/ZIOeaqIa1LxT55rbIwLL45puBJxGyCYJ/0t2A@BD2/PsDu7k/ptOVy2qzka1dJutwh@5XbPus9tX3UF59BWGMXzfoyCrZHiLwNU68KQo07QJb1sQzKPFzR1262CzRgUA548UTo4D1B9awIzSox2tMokFO6DX8mt5jZvJQZnY/roZfpiE7Ucin3HyrQ92RHNI4K5vdqpvNqgaOY0Fjbh9zs3N@@kg0DPvjDr7VB7PIOQNk3@4It59CLbQ/BkEW@a7WKZJVsTjl6SVrrXW5J5OvIPUtBDvxyaHfphWd1A8KP@LQ5U0eJZqKx1j2mGa96OBWjsDKEVw5QitHeOWIrBzRlSO2csRtB7fCzFmYoUMbDEY2zujGGds442tniN04NxhCgY0zuHGGNs7wxrlJLbROLRIjeOmDFTdJ1RV1DONCsVUY7jaHHg16hgEN99IzBIQGXkFC9NArT0gvtusZjbN2QgWmgkCBQGTzDtpnBZtwWVR5LTq8VsrWm@0JbRVl9d2IwGZ1HbRSdo5frQGhcx/TuPuOokDt0oIi8mAMiCZYKYkcyL/oPrZ2peuL480OPMSQ4NbvEB2PhIc4HPkAkyU@e4ID@4ItbIG92Kxt/fSaMVvbF20iLSqPd1paC2Nox28b6wdUsMjRNyACFgSWwe5@x1WaDX2yN8ng@0nuINyb5CuiLLzhfbGQNy6CPLGKStp/gi2xSs@yU0RS2mAG2J/bIzLwokDxeILEZ@7Y8btf/9n/Sv/u13/yW/qnf/7b/@ff/k/o/jd4@9/AZqEDa4Bf/Qne/ine/hFNZlbJjPEmEoEPHjt@@rPfwOv/@C/pn375J1bQP/wLhze0RgQh6LWJ@ad/B29/F2//h8MbXgP@6R9ZgBjF4X2mdkwrF0D96t/TNKSGWNbI/uwvadrhAQPDZUvenVXHH7Y2M1sI1my4I66Hl@HWHT9WAjxm3R4H4LXfuM2bBwvAvYVc5/H7cZu6B@aMNf@DWlrghT5uWLW9NAPtHwFNGM3w90DeZl0weuwxDCfk/m/Tx7TTgzBuXLnbxT4O0eF2/u18OzahCOtxMEAdfs7BRkU@5bKmBLq3FMg36QksDD92W0iPlLNkxOZvGb9PuWpAHCvJIl@2oOy0VrGh00PbX/kinzpZdXVRaLEZsk41IF/4oOwdldxWgjvq5kWxQSovfaDLuNnnvB2VeIijMRQJRFvzGxmLL4QL3pfoNiVnV5tsJfeiwuDVARNzuK2R1gklaIfjC7DIaRvejRZXcBfeotcGuGOPgw87u6b3ATuur68d1JYfizKkd10Ew1amLJWxDuJ2gwJbQYGtIKDZwkl0TTgQeEEDaThQL@6eEGBF21JRu9E2woU1Z1UOSAb0Ba1RTq@kTIx@4jVqopF3ld1r5FsouYeEXU/uVaJzzmiH@1UEwLkbJ/GyLPejZl/BvC6o/TGR2zs@O6X1NqadOFuVgnCPesmldclx8X0lt5vgO6i5B89XJhRg/4YJ@b4yoUj4ywm9LFaMu4P@bf5@We2s1MRaw2@QWRX/YKeBwqbxz0D0NuoIKdaJ0@WGLk/S7vJ0Zhrt2vM5N/BnVkdE7nzDTd86OBI7MWXNFK3hgU9jDbocGlrBWx@B3ff1Z/ubqz1V00Vj@zQE2dovqjrxPA5B66nQqnnxqErZ/kAhTq1bJy/ttivrls22QtPWd2URtcUotDwfH2VVNh8fwfhUJPeGgfjqF3ATn5PCD9KCayu@a23aVsYuDY/cNd1fxknsXStaQxaGrsrYDnRCIkkaOnSCqEDni@7jp6oMzWIJZtH6eBVYpB3TRY7G6msjrSeqGh5FgrFfoC9scCNB/HhMaPHSvJcWtiiyO9Euwcu77agXPzsqfRHAj62t4gd2Eewww0vrL3mMnNX3JPf4ZnJWtFV69Z9Pb32b3vr79EqybpgvaSaeONqDz5@XdNC1wQCAGzKCXybDa58@9IqcHVLW3viZRCvCV5PYFQ0Bmj@kNAmgSRvcL4F8eNdvBtmuZxPeeov/7xfgKnr2a4uPGLP1BeibEfmqGemiGeTsNVUQXQBecLs3a7u2kluLduYr07I7OqSH56UdRHGpuBcUKuZ4LKrGeqHUCvEXZB7X/LySe7IQKGEF7qFJn3rpYeDtIso8dkWFX4hdlw3p3cK7ynFN5LtEX31dxlHREaWnWd/GdLFebscUI3v2CdDxGyLDe6du99tiZYHIa@khk3GEwsLb/CMDdy9VMw6CJqw5EE0HDXpAjvUih6mNF@OFdc6HYn2T29ajVvtjlWQZjz/5IkOAD9b38TjvJln3e@qz5lpn6StahDWsfzfLZLfsqtnSwBp/VYY/j0VfzikZZVhHSqxKecc6eavE5fdKfEsqVjJpWSVfJ5JfErqvlrktUbOQbVRY@uc1Ia8wp3lFEQTXNkbL590S09RXOgH9sMQ09Y1W5XGPQl3HJJrOxE8GJSz7wk3J4CzAcwrPFjwRIfRBHy2BWuUN7drVkBcJGfHjLavF9rkT0Bbd4qJ7ex5xC4pauXEg93mdpvBmmsKrNIWdNNc1YDfJLSBK2EnSLgUsnveKQBEl8w3tjEHYc4fHe2obLlXjdZx7/eyUnceyl3ZOncegkJ2i8zjrAqXs7DqPM8RhOI/rxDF0Hl@AY1O3nD84j1fVAgF0eCWOT@hvq3B8F5zHaZf7mcKPcxurdP3O43WZAsxH65Vw5NkaXu3Ys/7aelRVxA@folHppVFiDHhomK27By/5sfBPQO2zMiHwQ4IOHBFg7IDsNBpbLYaVDjQbfvKld9e@5uN4NTRlj29sxlAg3JPYGlRBKZkQfeQ8cO4qI4swDCWDj/AEAlFvHu@niOZe9cy@RI6duoyfnAVm76ZPuOcn9kDXRcLvAHh7EEfZxF@V1y4KqwC/jk6M/Badr8hZJUcowsUA7j1kIVO/d76TKSzrF@cuWqW/XUKvxwiwEH0rEKuUCNotnQ42HNqmJLGxNt4VEhKKs33ydhy87EqJ0vsiGtEKds18I5h42zlDxbBd@d3vZWcrHpK2o4Iw8I59sGrZul0guhiDNrpuy1K1Kh@QsKVzuuQgJBHFNmM7CZylbrykrXirGVrFtZIkmmtXTUJkP242nvCmlfpmXga3IP@87usqJpjgQCMi2Iq5TsXSr9rPsN81y35fGdQrJrxIYJ9hvb8pfW1ev9vKvqBc2ST7ugAx0Etn3HuNo3UKG5ZD72DLMn9P1l6Z@Ph1ScvItxJdY39h7a/Ytu4TfIFvL/sWFi60EvTprucQB2aHgbcZ9doiUab@ldHix5RsPFbG15RusvY@rVbG9xUxhmAbDY@fXcD6bgFvFx7iIxnQX7DcquW4ZYbMU6zrNjnOZjNzYc06aLhKbH2K6JYnqHuyfm29RAs8Ko@1TKVcuoFGNxqNul9PRWCthbibdpx6d5pg3W0JePEgOOtb8RqupNHND/eq4/WSMuIBxgBP5m0s8bPruNvWZVv6/EXdhXgW7BZHbVzDTTXgd7QSmjo8NtmyzVfrKyauI95GsjJvgd9e0lvDWSOUDpzQeXwkzdfjIy7OeXy0WzEsmvU00u8P7I@bBjbrNaiD3dVMxOIyXp22hAMAk5H1cXd7AM4@R8lah4J7JgvmKvY61kQ15dViBxwfsr8lb83lu4Icjk4UpLUPoQMXZbgCIezCBsJ4doMVC6Fx4JMsrbTT@WAZOnicuDHWVHIgLDlkj5jteLi5sRp6JWRP1BlPloFYqZAjJ7YoshZkrebFrC/Yq@SgbIiLG@DIEPKKN15a7PnJjE8gDl2OoTy2zgldL/0w3CQSIZis0QIedxRxBCTVQXb3jCZfylAq/Zzc64EgMfaneawFLg0eovo0yZdenX91QLd4Re6uTmK214SRU9DtcWBgp2vnADODDkTAmop7gbObHzAWl8nQeEgZSxZpESj4ReERtZwx71bcD66Fe/fJrS434vvgesSStXYDyzp@hmfKq1t8tjcJbw1N25OWRA9szVyujsyi7LMTE2Se0o9r1MYux4FjdZYWOq1lE7wirI72cuGhcsfUNypRPLgCjBastTVg4KpotJHpNfd6SapK/4IOBsjnxiE9YqWSZAGHNbO3gx3CICoSa63usxWM4xddxy9wMpH65gB1oSVrGH8lyugmZzJvZJn@YKOzJlSwKltVYPUS3noJQlfjmz0Jf3A5PIDF43A7djABvD378Y2leV9HBaXo/j3T6EbaOS2ZTDZGnF47T/aS/WTtBt5TbMnTHoSyDJPNK91kptBZnGvRxlQKsI2bq1Qn6KlGu/OxnB@l8@MsJYduRp7b4DyeDy3D6WA6KbDX0nlJCkXT19K1ISYVMc5MB8OrrlgbdzjdkC/Kl@Xaksk1r1q9q4F0224PomqdGtduU72ruXgVa6vTVjNeMK7EVrpsDssDc8ItKtF2pDlTjVSrkeoXF4XZcF6IaDdyOH0lRlvSOD8TFuGxkG9St9NGP1LPL4ZxbtRdJNNG9ybq8TA36VQvlhe6t1Kxnr7o9vRwJzysx/ngdFSUxov@RV59Kg3S9angGQ9yhciUUquF6UwMtYcdJa/e1lqtTiZVnQ0543bcHYTalxOzE9MjweAkKfYHoXBhYuqxUip5ETUzyUIrp1y3zNtFK1alzLzZiDaLQlzxTCumEJxkmozBtuZF@aI@i@QDDS2vFpXCoDo8n5xXlfFkmAnJlcYopPeucx0tEMhf1af5mxKlh4rtm1htEIhlhLnAXIQ1bRRsxMsl/XI@ST1VxHZaqKfEToRNha@z3OCyshAq01Kt1q6O281R1LjglNscO6Aq10I9mRrmSqMY1ygvCrHzQn2SThfm005A6mnJSbcdvLyOzEplsdC@YoJ5fmJeeuR0RWEGxaKxaDUvCtdl4xaq9WVRDkmLeaqV0qWnTNq4rJWYsj7s10MDtTtuReW0JhSrhZBZGCbzs/ZtvJAailK1M9SGjbbSnphyZsDkqEV6eNXsiLOcvJzx2VCpdcUMsjXBjCZ7wTozkKTOUKkYy955admrTzq9brxyzmbEp4tuqhWuZcfcZc4IldUFddNISfKydiVxw2o8X7jtZJPypRpOV8Vx9Tw/nQcCN7JUnYWX3Px6kAvJcyHEliqp60vPVTFQ85Q8qVRVC1Z6VCCTO2/3whceLScumZLEP0XTHn0yCc0zk4msi6WmquijsMLGcg1PP2ro7fjl5axjFK5r6bagLGO3l8Nh5LZGXU8LhqYHYsVcMs5Uh6x@zg/KhduorOZCs9S5ko0X2stmzMyWJkosX@plijU90xgJ1/Fsr75YDHuxolgtDZOUGMvUaoNOr9WZ39SN6oK9DAmDjid7ni0/9aAet@q5QLGZivQmtWDrIqNOq42cZ6ldt0vjdHnIZauxSaQRDY6o6bwYS9ZNVR5nzi/jkauJXMomM71mmtNE8fpJuOCGfL2xYGNGVL/KXV@NDY/Z6GihTj8VXFxd3jCtW8MI52Xqdt6OFJJDXbjozs2iEW2oAa1yxXJXUrmphKdt@emmqg2SI@aieb1kOrNlbl41BbM@1MLdaHh4Pjee9OWFfkHFbga80iyntdJAiFzcyMsoE@bUxk1auhRuigE22ezlL8VcftpbNsVRYJB/muQFXjCqyZvOuRKZzsceKRiblqhGuX3diz49sR2xfBOXk8NmrVowAw2emdzUS@Gn0o1h5IRmQU6FZHWSSd2cD0fp2wXfMObLSSPSUaRFVQ@wWWpevrlsCQOtZ@SMW2GwvM7dqpeTQOS6MpCiZnfIjWSu1JLYaHlc82Q8VeW801tEWhNxKoBlOL4qjLlUcjCoUBVuFJ2mFnHDVM@Ni3InXUzKyWQpFrgaB6L5Yfo8P@/KrWarnO/yWui2kw5GKp0eG@imytleNTTqRavlaKiUphqdxVWN62ZiMtfnlfSguAiN46VAKsK0ZrX81aDRV8tKOtmeS6mg0NBm0TYvqU1xGYkyl6xn0I8X1SQbqkaoppkxm6XcLOhRLwqXgepiIVx3@EmQl55uDI9ws@wvKy2R15R@6anGNVqTUloeDFqRlNBgK6k6O1kaM35cqlLxTFXlMqX5NDfr19usMc7kx7HOvNxNV6tiZ9wNjqVOJTmX2Gm7fXt11ayoo@urUb4W7VSWXX4QbplSLVKZm9QTmDytaamZ68wzkiENatMn9Xw@uW4xoeb5qNTsTj2D@O3NNChfV9hSOdWS@Enhqhc1m@X5@LKoSAozClR6DDVrVpdLU0xq2fLs8mYutZbLpJwynrj5BcOXzguZa9MTz@aSmUqjzutKpXJeyiT50exyVrqOesRl/bIblodPt1RVVZWAfltXoik2aASa4cwyLQzO2cl5atQoNuLcmGvmW5eXF1xfEUZC9KaSibQvhXYyWbxYFCW@Va2OqxfNBlXxqNe3tw2m0lBKcalUqDW0cGGqX7bbUX6mJa94thAadWaleWp2OZm0R/Gi58YU@aC2FEWuNlNKjJgH2YlR4mRaTZerxiLwtBw89aYZ7boVT47PI8n0QupOxemSTWamHsbIzWfdiDyOBRo383PpRrjs9S5qqX5wPB03IukwVYxLl2qrk@5fxhfiRb7Uyk1Msd7thGSPwY4Hjatk02gKC/lciPSnTeNGgconjcONVDpuKLeZ2IUue9iYkKKE9iVfZUr98HW52NVm6flla5GBLkeMk6psWFuorUlsqOYvjNRF@@kiFus1O/khJDzp3/YFuelJdTvilaSUqdvri9YwW520mMHV9WW02sx7Ysugfv4kaP1zPr5oLCssK0rx3rQwmQfHJSF2HruoCEpxXq41JbEXqQeulHN1SWXUaJ9NStxsOlMZzyKcimV7UqpZVvVMU8hHRa3KM8y8fWtW2texi8A5e8XWRzM2YFzOGFa6UeXFTfnmJtClUlPjYtyuc9OsJ28mb@qDmnCuMOV2rbDUFqVswGgmy2npYjJbjEsLWQ/eCqXztFIVZA7MknCk19Cbw2Vq2qHa0ryUTsWit4E8SJBhKPHZTYgXBWPcmw@Y0uUkr8wHk2FL94zmTM1zezMPx/utvsEIpVKjXJhl9bBWNAYqFYkIgXxbH0eN2tNoUUibmX6rqYTS8VavU8nfMJcN6SJ@la7fRsVwlSk8ifF2PcIKpXBbYLiaNpqa0CIJvSFVWrBdXVBEnY9OKk/h7GTi6S6mE9Mzvo2eX8TavWGamwq8J5jsaE/8vFVUWLkcFXtGpT2bXufaYCGqrWlTpXK3zXHwQs5L9Xyrcjnkqsna0mRS8bZwHerd6JykStNa0AwXC2IvKkiZ7O1wkMkXngrsjfTEzjhFv7oK5vIcFZU8KVPrKkzranylLgO8mLypxC5n3WV61C9LYr4QyOg3tUi3fsErWWhG5acSO27lzku33Y7SZyRNrdRrLEvdRgLZ9nXtiZt2r6rLhjbP671isqoEr6WCqlWvW1zmSmfK0VTuKj2o3aYXsUhVVzpioxdrqCPPeVAT@KRailBRcSqmWm2mKcpBLjpfdvihyHC37eEwlmeWEWPJJFVjNoj1lvHO@Yhr35a188ZiyJyP5rfV1DU3ET0cVxXG1JW5rIbPz9uei8V5s9BTmgVJYPjRYmDkUxOxOOtcRZKe2JhteLLdVn9eqvbG7SwT7XRiXD0YbIfMp251YVyVqVamlA9GMwtzLmWHk/I8lh8nI/XFvHkVCg1vB/NKrB6phefcVBtmU@NcL8xo10ZUnTfyvVxKzEqXknG57AgjKrKclAu5WNYTFvmb6s0tK2WZp3pXMfs9qXFxHaxHGCGcr1Rnt7eZJDOKSoNsQTmHNnHGX84X9cHNsHNVMYIypVVuPIXIMrKs316Vu2q1Xbzsd2a9aLSq51uD@GR5M67JNc942Sx0tPNMdaRkltcgcJFaPDxoKtlmW77O1NgKZUbayRnY4FyqJC96TCHMXkgqW5yPzuPXo3ZkeDNspae1m/lwEKlHw9pEXEbN9lN4IjajN8VRnRE6N7O@J3BOafXl4jp7FdJL5dm4ZFY18YKNBUq3w@YoO2l6RumLXMdMt9lxJ9AuzSaedBisgthlKx4ody4GqcLw/MrIXwXiVCMnLyaxwXnk3FOFxmQyMCqxlhJQpkybUVqzqTgcsXw5w7f0eaeZK3XL3UCMGXvk6My8iDwVb6q3vDkOqQxlLCLdGe/JZ8GCyMg34bqnZY7ZEfRF2Otp8ELtBQOGel2vC2Zaiw6bwbgYyuktVWvNtUErIF@dR4czQb4YUClx2Q0pzVq7W54vZ934MNTl69NmMnettoNpddyfGzoXiV8EWvxTdaQHK@a4WmoKKfVqxPPSzDNXUplLvT6lur1ystvOPU2kaStUSYaSi@suG5rcTgecurzO3gQG1U6yL81q7dCyNgumuuecWhvJ45EeYNhGS80OY/NmXrygisusuOjHrlLVVqh5MYgPg0pvWK@yi2FFloTbW2PCFW56pSuuWwi3UlfxYV4ykmK0GZeKA2Ze7lRuI@muGGIpT78wYgLpkhAsZq89ZlFQwk/ykiuby7ikLspNuVPvTZPjUnfQnJRTeSbFBabn88oomK8xwQmfGsUyF/qNrlBiNpycNyuXEaN/mzRbIa0amMbGt1W5dx3oVvu8MGIjMdDBl93O7aKZrKVmpZtyvm4k1d5S9OizC/W8kMulVCovtctPxhOvSZNkqFkp3Vw9XSX1XiPcMY0CN38SmcVCrRTTgrC4SRaMYblVrKuFKDvqpi6jV/1uSW1qVTl4QQnx6PA6yqh1oThhxVA1Gco9tc6Fp8I0UtOGqik0srecWa6BsiuEm5XxzWy0TPdZaR4MZa@NSq87voXaOlhSgUm@dtOtSQN1PqsVzdZFcFTnhq2ZMoyo/NgTysYrFZ7rBbETFr7W1JGmXPTM63p5eqEzTH8ZmYjjc/FCpkqBcS9ZqEWKAf78/CYTb3Kjp5IYiF2GJslZoFK79KhhcZwp9EYKmx7WBuKVDF2GdqQ6KLL1stzs3U7S1/FFnVredKS4WmzPtIv0cJYZTgeN5jwI3atGq2QY9dq12S1MA51iVOlU@t1GJpe@EtI8b0QrajpbGY4nrc5olg@FqUEueD24jBblXmQYLYiLm4vJOF4tLgvpfj7kuVGLMfOGN5WnijJ4KndMs/MUlVv1qyLTTkUFlX1aRM3rfpsxqHxslD0PidFloc9Fm@poOpl0KzVVKyyqV5fA5mgg2DjvMMlx@6pqtrp5UbjON8HSL2pioX5dHNfPr/PdSVellCCIb5rRL85LRu46M7zlZoXaoiNznmHlYlYJR8NSvOOZhkfl/iQTDrejo2J5msuM9cj8ErR@r7qolsRa@ZLiRpc32aGnKHFcTL9ctqahWlK8jnQuZ9IsFM4k52o/Fmuy86viuXAV64wLs1GzyPWumNltfGiM@CZfSwqaVKFST@PgIjM3s2w4exHJX1@Jg8ism50ECslZvV2ImPGy1G6Hnma12VAs5zipMZ/OAtVc5cpUQ@F56@p2eAGlEKaE3vwqGxUvQ2KXlZe3aT2nddQmn2SZIhOYNVtXHq2nPpVFz7AayAXHkSw7r/LQM75NTYrdSKc5UNrnqXy8T3VDQtbTMCKF28jT9dOlrF8PPNERqJyYVJteXYJJ0jGbjdD8SorfcMtWOtbmO7kll71gkqF8fhIvBALFUrx0Qxn18Aik5WkWuC5mlMBVtdUITTyZcmbe7ddvm7X07DJ2e8ONqu36tIidsSDDzqTKoNZclHPzpixGssNaVkpRnsLVzKjEx1It08rqTLUr5UKDYf48dy5OLoTJPKt62F6huZg@TUZirHip8KKu5mpmPykEb2LD4FwojJNPFy1qkeezRS4da8X0oSwUB@WmMTCm7bEkJ0NP4bnHrA2q8kU4U2tcq4Nmv1zWhfRlIGqImWF9FLltDuadqZjtFinJjE8FZX5ejphqapGTr5uXV8VunV0I1VixnNPnbIfJPdXZqck0Y/Vqo9cp63JpAA2n56apaTEFVIrZ164oftwvsLNW8qIb6xnpczZWKs4rTbnsYa@ytUEmYEx1D9MfVQKZpZYtBqVZtFe7uhixenra7XsuqlHmdpDSZmUqbHaDbd4YxmsSd3PTYsbZ2tIwLmPNjufiSmHEWuA2msovuUYnOO5O@jexm9H59Onm5vKp06rnoTivPWKkfvlE9a4u8kZUigtct5lKl5LadMwW9VFNCo1K2k0zcCN5buaZwuwpcMHmBoUOVy73l8uUUNTbaiwz6lym@cWgGWtRwWyF7d4GxXGxmXm6yfUnAyFdmgvBay1veK5D5fnkXI9FI1woPuWNYGs0anliSUX2RIP9RT@Qyk4jGaar19pUtuJJtzUNakHtNsKXGSPULSum0Yw26tl4LZ1L50sX2WupFK8X@Otrz81VIZ1NNiLFi/4wdHHDGSkmddkf1APUoJQedhnTjE3kupwzsud6Zt6/HV6NJp1ZdFoybpbqBT@ReyNO4sfDdkmNRpJXradwhQ1mL5ns7VJRA9HwPE51BalbZJTa8Lodk7N55kbpQwc6A/I/vL6c6IKkG/14G3J@uVSj6Wal19LzSr8KFCqdyViQRnF52BeDt1SNqcdy0bZyIQmVm9ooetORrxvFYFSazKH/epNZXkgZBkq9eVPvT9jrSBZM11DoqdDuj66m5ZZRC2dajVI1RLWeahmJK2RLpdat2eXKFbaXm5rNaCyf5YRRaljOLlKdVGGWE5rtvGfgCTS6wjTXSirZVpc35otbNs7qSWlARQaRy5SU4cxZuCXpoXSxXwnySkGbV4qx8ahWLQZSxeyVpA11NnWVXF2R1iI@@n@Lu9atNpIk/Zt6iqSwjWRKN2z3dCOgW4DAmuU2SNjNwTQWUgnKlqrUKgnQ2PzY/bEvsA@wDzcP0htfRGZddAF6Zs@ZmdOmlBkZGRkZGRl5i/Deja87lcreh9rZ9rVV@dv2zpfVD52wdeKv3NUYbGu32/zjT7sKcQcDn8Gs28BrI1xb6Go3F@VHHE@w5wk8b0/5ncBln6QjgY5@Xy2Bsh37FC@E16QSPtvMI5QPjhbLk2eLuZJxJ8B/4MdDvWbvg53UQag9QOGIjEXPf4wAPvHkExScg/Hz5JfhGv1HNDgGJbGJX9RlmDfZJ2ljjsDPB3zIFi/KiSPPTClJDQikLmv6HeKnY7@EV4VXVJCPgKtHu9lZx/rFcqo8ERf2ffY0YufyNhfVXjGAKY1CehPpkW8Gix2ymIO1R4ITNgulH4s//MT@PZTvDJ3e@U8XzuvWhq3codf0e@FocNf@eh3c3HZUV/W/XN23xn//Xal3bxUcGq2@Em@apR82Cuze@y/sf/Qn9gj@wvhM5QAMn2yl2PciXLQuKxV5uSovqix/OPhnzS5PSal63TNSKE4@euc/XGz4G8Vy79y/KPsrK9nhysZwpbSSQcKrUrbcH@mbiOfDC361X3itDszTeoTuwd3foKOOA791EyyH6r7qtlJvTth3mRlAvWY/OZ5u3dYwGCRTOpCnZi81EKeTcErcnCjpBQZuOO67OLqLvBJ0A5Jf/LMw@uFteTofLVxYgAuNsr47kWzAN6s/uup6rTVrgfmJI3A8p19b005hWgpyu7DAaZ4kCi3KCzPILpvcVtAf68KegFyatqwnUG5mcLaadZ4DaaCuSCYvEWhxQGACIuxNgStCzUejWaEK3/uuH52Dwo9PtgwvJ2rR5BmPP4CH3LDfncuh8thLD/1ZVxqUfWCorPY4wannHh698VWCzWXJWvgy6vX5/Dkv9GqOIIr0Zb/pDaKS@XB0hde9qgRmeIZo9AA@HuAN7rY5dJNdY/oCF9/48RXaA3zHHAqMCG41B4MxdCMeHwBfO@AyCxKmPKOGgVysFDJ0WW5GVnc1MQ7O95f7y2uK78GVKYmPRMuJ3C@Ui7bOye5Rdq85vJmTfQPco3Be9oCyEbx8TrZH2fImcnZ@QPly0j8HYIhbniSul8Pgctj0uhlx6AFXIA@isDNqZcUwNhIBJR0j/ZEur7RrFLUovSPClhIvGp8sVgIAkc7owYPfsbRwLpz0ZkQuEnUKT9Q39WRl@nIksfiSayK1i/qzr1P4VYIAGn@kStV0vqlcejtqaEp@8jTtXKO3iVlv1Pfvj1GmBTEtf6ULI33SQ7iHm2ihcCvGI7GV436VQn/XhWaX0a5jktrN3JGI22EG5WqsQmRsxeO64/ltqoMQLyaTceUpq36OU87DC7UWaY@YjzIsnubj6pT04EYUj0hHXcWfredztQm5p5JNmpGvYmUBP2HN8hQ7wwg6l4beJOiImxNy1krJjB6lf7axz2vNEtHHg5p5UxZF2yLTcFMTOIO8pvRrUicIshfLa5KOSNBeGpk3B5n407skBMN1ogEzm1HjZk70/Ly8SSU9X1x96/AVcwF5iNlklNVz@PT/MLjAOD1ljxAcM62S1AzWTIFH7Qa/NieH3ETzRNPPbty5PGpe/nkZNKppeWKp@5lmyTVVVJHjprJ6eFoP/XOc@RZ3X8reCTPzdYXpdCOJzxHBhzmMflLI0k1YvVApjoME1gxPTEnshHD2pBRfrb80KebapYztuRYYqCqn80GzIDQZZCgnSzna5tqMVaf2vng5NMaNE1thiEktUkEme9lKqnMs53Z58k6mRq6jmCPJHLxkh4U5MJR5HWPbkhlsyuVbl@hmYTL4SWP6OgjaGWMwaYOBMRgPHQTkiDuryKwS8zKunqrTRq@61l4@zLxbppRFncTzCiXA@NSyCSJeX/OwKWPYJOwbL@SQ6ZyP2YiqMq8PcFlRtI9am0wHdGQCLcwsZDQ@fJKx50qt53kmTqkHe7vp42IoxwzgpfW6jfSoIwCzSQvt2L8l98HDjF0G8eGpvVt@Sy5dvLKXh00cdbq5BZktR9Ssr9uoJnb4/MfSYmEUDgpXnl9w/Vsyqq/G1pJyfQmauaZGw07uR1wUrpzsfdDahO9l8yVEEhPqKdSW9927DGDIcoYXUTtriU86vrRYsuCWmO@Nd93bNln94rGlH4T3/O@YFgvF/Kg/DDhHV8S@69R373vsT7XIr4j0ikGTs854YpgM3hdI6ljuSuZKYiCV4HI5m0BxjpKscO1Pto3@A6H6Pun5hRXm3WbrBkRA9r7Lcoq6iyX5wQpN18PXGliBxyv02RUvE32@O4oq2DoJx/ybmo/fJXxICl9xhdzrdYrFF4KR0w2CPoQcV0FRfp0YIIxfqDd2qicneR1VS26s45a73GPGE0F2WMeRFqJrvLitDneB0ikLaCxwS30bMXLWv8wjVKvZhKFwB3YKr@CPUFqQK/GvqWZE8FkBZ5bwcyf9KwQvi9qrR5/sKPAuLpZJFMuZYgY4wYqFJ7nRbLXgCOLA7QVE8bbb7RLRwouFmB34BEdM/StR/eE56ryIiJf83FR@LpWfl3whKobKt24GMdBaEshe@hbDPSg7BnOm6tpQ1OjaIXuXygeDBN3lx2DDPC3SvBh4M@pKkcooYz2VkUvk/Daj9yVnMVUmEvAo/1zytXyv6p6PqEzB/pKuH38t3UEu@2DQTxYnpDTve92fZfsxymENq@BWSYqjv1nsZFDqDRGtTnKkJkiIedhubsRYVkpG4/CYsTfXf7Hzekvq58wkGVl@ITA1sGaMkQSXuM4VZtw9zyRUD2cvJlAwTgiaMiN30xQe68LjBFpALZpqLeMpND3AqWmTQ3wD17q/4x8z2NPEGbil2ZkLQvm9NF5eWqQZxEp30Z7NprQ2GQ5GriTqRj0yi8R1jycxzlYShwFWoK0baIqoTlfeg3SCkd9ejPREUlEYTTHF9yhHczoGKBnxndeFyHyw/ii8tvaaPbIKu@69qsCmbrKjfiv12GbohsMQ0YiogQMVjvr9rqf9uqk7fs4h7SytvsNjhBhjwmjIWzU8EBV4B1/6cQwVyqsjYL7DO8M4IxxdX1PF2Am@Ce6gWjseoRzmrYo/Zs/E7AZtVZ68uGoEP65QwF1a9iWIkJ6T0cM7D7DS8pZ5WCRN7cj49odkAlHDA/Z5CFera5b1t5HX@rq9p1aLxb@Uim9KCZaZrepi/s1bVUuYSCZjtVgqFt@V3lrWdtAfy9PGTCsLXG9zQOiofUz0H0g23VvX912rQjMGA4Zk@ofu4NZt5y3rxG3zHvDViDkCUR6BXb7x84oUsq3g757M3V7oKFp23UC94C/mZ/Fd22LHGo6FN0R9d9DzhvLSKLj12mCgeTfVCbrd4I43ovFkSfiBQj13SEx5nVVpktgvraaFbRd2F0vcQMgHduB3FdyyH2nNBrJTPbjf5wdAFpwoAkOyMr89QQnV1@o2vR7EaQYB8LIUc8AQQE1rj1ruozRYTMSfpEHphrWD1gieeZumZwqk/QIeKzTc3YFH2jdmMPcKF0vQTh3ceF@rq/rRbuNj5aSq6Pv45OhDbae6o7bOVON9VW0fHZ9xCC71/miftEtdVQ53KPWwcVLbOm0cUYJdqVNJmzOsyuGZqv56fFKt19XRiaodHO/XCBuhP6kcNmrVuqNqh9v7pzRZ7zmKMKjDo4barx3UGgTWOHK4VlPMisupo111UD3Zfk8/K1u1/VrjjGvcrTUOUdku1VZRx5WTRm37dL9yoo5PT46P6lWFhlk7tfr2fqV2UN3JU/1Up6p@qB42VP19ZX9/oqFHHw@rJyA@1cqtKlFZ2dqvck3czp3aSXW7gQbFX9vEPCJw31H14@p2DR/VX6vUnMrJmaOR1qt/OyUgylQ7lYPKHjXOyjzBFeqX7dOT6gGIJk7UT7fqjVrjtFFVe0dHO8zrevXkQ227Wi8ra/@ozgw7rVcdhXDAXDXhIG5RPn1vndZrzLfaYYPmjNPjRu3oMEud/JEYQ1RWqOgOM/joUFpLTDo6OQNW8IE7wFEf31cp/QQ8ZW5VwIU6cW27kQSjComJjWQz1WF1b7@2Vz3criL7CGg@1urVLHVYrQ4Awol6P1ao0lNuNfqJ6JJPElbLSK7D3alqu6qy86EGyjU0SUC9pqWF2bb9XvOcxnLBmnnk9ugB3vQpn94KedxJ/PbRTpUsPokDY8fppzTp/Jg@vEvl0UQTZdJPfQrKc9Vl270aXV96fifA0jwqJifYvfDaQUSlLMI3f7IeiZOoD8q5wNLS5eWHyiWtc@uXl1nnOSVTZDxVQnthfQwqq9vYDZptXuan9paSjNp8pX29O@J4ObnX8irafMiqQqHt6mJ4vAjEZptIByUgZG1oRn7V2PRVoko@Yk7vFXHEjMnNInO8GYT0j/89/iFzQyKBlLPcWygUsIZlMhD5REX0UyUcFERHBuF7AF6Hq8yHrvv1OlNMVoclv96gypoyDDukZeB1JvtE8Sv3eqJ4brI8E4u3pmysGHfwxk07BDPgX5plSvdLfsAty8jWHv/JGmq4IjIKs1IVP2TVt08yr6Q4/IvKXmG2HLkS53AgB5Vfax@xmCuuvi1PpL@P0mVs4dU5YtvQfHfO5S74z/sLAaAB5mH5RSzxxnKkWigkypBVxvZkBAxf9TcAuvPaNKdiqr5xeVqHh3xxF5wsT5PxwLtPUk9qeO@kcrB1urtLmhPUvv3x3V9@KFva4/5g@Ksjf89QD4fjBHfJir7zyEzjrMQo2Sa7Z3cqWE4iug96D4CIHmk6jRObZNJGnjPFRpD4GrINhOaGiDDgI8iGjSABA1vhfb67aBl5nTkytQBkUk3NojW95j1b@E0ylVgGWuIlszvmXrvHP8AdDX8zxKMGaQHSIub2@sMxSS4tLljv2bvG4QCvbfhZMUDytpHjftPcQRLGQGeyFwa8wedfWrYTvUh2LToa45W7nUsSEYuTVJggLRxyiao4DkIzgiXRo5RftbzR55kODoQshHqoDOvExt2oZM4E75E9Zz0wNOaLzQ3qolevoprWFTZSs5oo2f9Ph45JjgYmRS40qAnE5uZRxOcohzehf1nOqm8iqfDqDTxlLbH6N0nurOZoLGXjEl3/NhFklOCKA8pw0l1Uh2VAzgxIxM4Um/4lfjD@fyNPZuBfpwUnYY@5xXrY80fuMznJWIVXtHplpnh35sZY4ppazM1k0lmM5iHZMTdRw/Q1vHs5WCIW6N4Zm4QzCSmWmcEACDn2NZLjFw58eRDfNGnl9AuP3QU56R/4rV4/YwJymaliCu@FwzaXY67I4UdWjvCLKlHdPuKr/MJ@HllnYMFFWuxqrF6GtuBYKbHOQaMLr3nTIxrlLJpgQ8mM8FicinpomcF/r28YxbNM2@Q@kCk6P9hXdByCmEIphW9OQIwC4btPyQZrtlGdmyB0Zrvh6YV3@ZWexRH5klQgz8uqwe45wmaH18yYirQvDTjtQJXA87KtYzZducM7TBddwc4@RGJsKvOS3ZigEr0XGZkRRvlm88R1nmTvIup5mxLyGlF/6n/1ETjZlS0uA5FPRYBKumDNq4MmB4PqPq/ddlz5Cti6ma6/5rNflZacV2JrjlfuVAtW@i/DmCNkcd7BuqR5KOZSs/UVibaRUe8u593TH64rp1tuYhrRmoEj1s0y@h/mLgggKxN3YJX9yY82kdZkItt4acwXfMnYjb7O8KX3mTeoUUQcpeDCrDaDQDLsJlzSnB5tTF/KrQ4un66R5XR3l79qjnpNv9Psed0x3zr9Etz4hdAfhf18f2zZtp3eDYQjcLhIIdqHrvro@e3gLlRbNBywkVQ/PK0fpzf@Ejtf27LzpdRfqQ61xTVbU@g78JkUBp0hdY1bVmMd130Qb/fwPqHeaeFtrTES4JhqwAJE9fYiy3jv8FTtub47IHvwmO9cqn2v5fqkPsiY4luY4Y1oGoDvova6rl3twnbhnZ2ycj3e1In29ixdgcbmQLQyNBSJ4IEOq4i9@TGJemJPMD/d4LhdbbOpdBP0tTcgbJrC2JQtzs6o61iI3fix1niPxbgszHlvhqY1s9eHvUQxnXqyWUuNGTT94ZiYYk1u3hDZT@3d5BU7AyKM1nx28qKuh7jrbWz7dUNq6hl1ntYCPIPQUHW9WwSL42245/QR37PV22Yx38rav6Ij4euM6kj1nhX3noOYoXlHvftJNVzIrjruNlu0wlL1EYq/eUN24FYQDgF6UFGquFoqlXKlN9iiPa1X8jwQ8J@JIGZZtYPjo5MGMVK7yDeCEc2ZYD4H7ZLbWMSOHEJ3Ues/QyEbeNKYq5@ZeTDBjR9fuywnFvaaTX3famK7l1oYps1h3pLFlnww4MBh8AZFIpQajlQrnB4gRB8rSdSUwO5w6DIdfEymlohO9ubHBT6Dti7JVRfnoZ@5MKeRAnDvOY1KDXhl0NZu76lPem4vot4bmtm9KQDWZMyziGGyl0rCsewsw0oi7mWTeNou7kiEiB7QC29bA9ItzVsSOVxhMS6xSGZYN2Wj1jSvvK5HY4Doat0EmHBEXZmO4C2IZEQ0i3s8irWDCYlpmRGtgEZXO@hFoEKVZUXO4HR6Pxy3ArV0TctsrLTCvuu2OVLCqC@hAJCfp1HepZlD3MStxTECrKUi35sckLJBSBbSfaMufMfC19@V9LllWkNSZdwLNm6wrBdE1KL6kAcpIrZlZqywHYVz3ix3e5MEAmWzYMQcR3@Eou/gUIqoov5mgeAvFhcH7qi63N@TfgBRkIMRhf10BnDJqa6bzjDo0Xb9OQUgQroRETDhYtAQI36y5Du1B5b@gfbi3imcpmWkjdS4cTZi5q6HEJqyNxCo6wD/AjhvOCZnhC6fEU45LryHS17CNwlZmoYkqCiASAJydQbO3Eycb2bjzGmc@rCy5t@ywzaUYrGQVog36ID0IxgRN38vMKqX3cp1Azlgilp/3Q2uELeJNAXVhj9jJ@7YZDKvwFKMTuaKE8F0vKl10yRNun7bZGwXtU7jw91U62bHYvOTLx2lMzZkLLHPMsVzFw8n/sQ/ekTxp50KXgWrYyJ6FciTVNLdQGtrlDrFXlPxyMRNnCS8rjldpJcqUpoooolLF7lKFVm1Yk@lE72LElD9@JtumbFL@FYS94DaiDqoaPWa97K6KbIDOt6mQcjIlEe81QstIAA8b6nIpx3AL6zYRXPq2F7qMD/5Ch7f@LZf2BzyqpiOd3Bvru6xGmCoVP6Y3YD7Gd2grGYD/4jcP2cNMbpd61zET2iqqMGSYaWaPcBbrUyyluyaWuo35dQQUCEmtmTV58wDnNLb9P/XKqMryCWJFSC41dWqkBjPrpfPaSkr3WL0YNGKZ2b@lVBw1IOW6G@@MibTQCaTGldGc0c45XNKdxMqpAs6rskS/58h2XWSihkloRrqMPgQxlQbee49Lc/4jJlR8PwT7VjrRPFpHGkPTfx5XPOFmTXSrZgLPTmVzIJJzCoRFx4DNsyO@DQXeP5sw6zDHgL0nYAnWLePTWLNOjMFL4fCMrZSvCE7Ow1anmioNNsSSlfKOjMUcLrLDXHORKushCtz3cLJacRKzZwpIckkfiFMu3opgewEUdZKlQL/53U4rjsmB/ZcuJLA6W6fJxERLtPvj4lFBGz6/TGxEOBEtz8uFiaWYcRaLj8pF6meEBbgUqJeMfCeUlIHmYz7JNT9BBQTNL5I@jJ3u5kZ1Ca0qt7rtKZMpYhFOnRJug7@cy8ds6QdjabEkZh3HvXGRdxamuNaX9125JFZtz5aIm3a6SlBenMyEAEabWrgPrrIImR2VIA0tmyC6TVzT@5uskf7ZVmw8BoUUbuub9Kve1NozaxSzE4blMZ7f0z8@kzic9NRFOIl1tp0fPjodpmmGheegkEb0LY148TXeoKqlQRV6dYleijN4jmYcs/ClHsGpkICkx7Yb2i@5M@lAeLUuU@h@PRpGgf/@Y0WUhoHadq2h01srIPvmuOncC6SsbXEd@qacqssKhDbyU/h@HkSB8cFvYlO43TiTRO7bn93B8FkVI65nE3LygyKIqqWpslyQBZrbV7vajhjKvHaNv/16saLVgJLT/e0@DHWhXGV@CY6BFpKe9WPkMXjvzSHf06iW9PjQQhPbcOQtWz9yeGQByNkh0meikUFEoosvQ7VGWlGPJ47qfx4tTrp/RgBT@cWyz7Zkl9kwyex6VSiponGSkmcWcLFysnMVka/zVqePVn/0sz6@0GfbJzOTAIYvod9fNmUmlDpsWk6sbR@1lw2cz6bblfSbpuITfL8Qf5qqumr1HQ8TKdB7bt3evZ/DLNui@mBf8KSPzcyMofIlzOJxEF7U29uKX/Uu3IH1nOGupTI44@skeZLrmUtLalKi5bM2jM@dsVaHL7P1VXCDIYghGrUx3lNKJc7MbixR@aKAE/CtoM7n6HzNqrgPdqe2/S1q3w9YV4PcH4RwToI34nHXVyD57eI0aGb2P78LDGp267OwY3kR9hant33kGrUqalw4po0WWJrZsbpNa2kzjFwIquGodYmDRUjOzgMfS2WubaXyDDPzt4Ce4719JhBREI8r0q94J1A/biMrs1n5qgfsTLqmmewcpa5Fe1yP8PcGj/X3Po3cHKyQ63Et7Ye9AS79qRSm1zkW38UClFgxt4M1y0fGru7KYcnV2OzKui5g3fFYhFOcK6aIZ9apLzh4JTYCwpp6AL2xAv9u78OPlwVUBSHFohMsGYOM90w6JKqCfPB4FqiUYAGAgU0jiYgJziaGNF8kwj3gP0cH69yvoQCKR542oqvcXrR5fYPDRY@RgnmuWvqMxqI9n1WnZEvm@h3TVkyaCzmvhmVhhl6a5trcsQeJHTgUSe6ksbIeN2sXy3g4GNj85u1wGfg8lyQw8Vnv8XPEO33brcbOOpjMOi2F215HZousLubLFAUEFwllMETcvhiR7m3XjcRwhkgoC3ouvlucM3ocAKuny3yW6aB28dJWgbz2Il7Xb3vZ@zz32wSTGryCpq5ouwLPO@5tmmKsvkI/Wm0EjCDyH4WdK/Zz7SYT5PANAfqt1TxF1H0puSoutwOxn7KNjUZlzkyKZCs@IURnj0NDabOJjf/JfD8DDUd2Raey/HTb@5ebskc8Ii59qf7Ugc8LAoOTRNC9DyvxEMZTqf@@f9hdxs7B3jcyHu80ZPYhL@xZDvMZjxGlroddjo0vGQnftO4GjPoWFXmSnxLAazRHTtwf0esgsxyJ1yWACu4alMf@60UIeerF45aHg07Py4Thn@pjZYZgXr4ET9xbeI/cjSsd0ccxzvWZ7wNhwsU03oHBS5RwLJetjZ@v8tUKhX1or@yoiqVLfrI5VRlq6J2kLC1pXbo9xZ@v9pYffeuLDfndrLfKHHLJD6oLcLBU9AKLQR26CflbWBFhaUUuvhFYeOFU35xubG@WQ4L55Wti0Lhmr7@8Z///Y//@p9CRf/4X/zY4h/nv0VA@Xy@8KL17cWrhzJ@n@9cLL@4On/Rv1i@LkPK/g8)

I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c) compiled without `POINTER_REVERSE` defined, so Up and Down 
actions on `*` conform to specification.

2L code is after Wierd:

```
# + 
#+
#  +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
```

Retina does not like `*` or `+` to be the first character on odd lines, so I used four pluses at the top to move the rest of the code to the right. `#`s are for SILOS.

[image]
Blue asterisks print digits by decrementing TL1.

To fix evil: removed `mxf` from `>{-<<` line, added `xf` to evil line.

#### Refactorings

**C(clang)**

```c
char* x = ...;
int f(char* a, char* b){ puts( a ? "124" : ...gcc stuff... ); } main(){ f(x, x=0); }
```

Clang evaluates arguments left to right, so `a` is nonzero; gcc evaluates arguments right to left, so `a` is zero. `f` return value is `int` instead of `void` because of Grass.

***99***

Moved *99* before Incident and added exit statement to it (first three lines are the same as before, see [answer 99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136698)):

```
9999 9 9          // assign 0 (9-9) to 9999
9 999 99 9999 9   // assign 881 (999-99+0-9) to 9
9                 // print 99 because 881/9 = 99 and 9 is a variable with an odd number of 9s
 9 9999           // exit: go to line 881 which does not exist
```

So now *99* does not execute lines after Incident line. Underscore on line 14 (`L_9`) is for Cubically.

**Whirl**

Added exit statement `000011100` to Whirl on Incident/Whirl line as [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41388909#41388909) by SnoringFrog.

So now Whirl does not execute lines after Incident line.

#### History (offtopic)

VIP score is .001863, [Henry Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Ford) was born in [1863](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1863).

Answer (score 7):

## 163. [1L_AOI](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1L_AOI), 8160 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |       |            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*size
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   @125iRE                               _
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkhj4uVL3D@5LMMEuZBJA4kGCD4BAFYqPKnazilySVdU9IAqVSCSILAKZ6EyABIrFtl3d2WhnV3YnzY7WRrOn7Zk9nd2anT6sSTozyXbNzuz0VbY/oufj2tnNP5hz94h84UGyZiTTgQQyMsLDw8PDw8Pj3dK97m9/m8APO3Z6k4ueM2RD0xuytmtdma7Gnk3YU93yioVVSUKomnsx6pv20CtJCZZnzLINqw3vbOhcmrb10XTBv8DYwHUuXL3Phl19yEzP0Aemx5zRcDAaMqczP9oqY3t954OVwZh9y74AsKHpDlxzSOFrjL22e3q/1danQopTCQ5cCPfYrtn71P80ZIbT7@t22wPIdcZeOq5nIrxhep6D0TcYG@@ZxhTSTQDVXcs5rL16PhW0xdhzIFEf9Mwx01ve0NWNoeXYyJMcO331@vR4KkY@z96c7e9P@xbYVxnHZvsj4zIWRLw@dp32yEA@DLsmBCPvOlbP9CQD8lhlA1FiGjpYgrmm3uZgUsdxGUZh/cses5gxGLBWT@9qButZALuf22Qmspp9hPBe12PjQZ95Vh@weE7fjNLiMds028wbmIbVsQyigJnjoWl7kGNPYxbQfm31eqxt9iBCSJaRBmRs5EW8OBGa1HYkBh9jMJWJ4G3ZBBjb9BlhDqAkkBEOFhxwxefHtasPBkAkMPMUCB9afZAza5j0mKl7FkoyRPFMu008HAQy7jDdjuaSXVk604HekUu4PdPFAtUIL@uargko9UDKlGvXGgILkMU1dmzqLjtzTVONy3ssSUjMwRSGmBGNinB7O7l3tJ@EouQxNH0wlBLu6tkffCnpTKuw5WYZvhVZLkt7r3bZzfI5url4Q3EPXEVXWeU75mXPz034jvOt7IV7KwFWCbjSY1lnMMzqmQEQmBkCgVkdnejKXBW0QS@SMNueKouIgHGoNpQGO7DZmzTlzBi5LlbhkKn6JWS659gXwE/IrDuykR82W89BERgO1MA0M6@AayDyVEbONXH4rGtBoXlYJJHKxBURMRRUEcie4Kifruf0RgQHMb0hCiBwBaIixoMOe8M6utXDKBCOqDjVrumNekOMM7LbWPKgaMy2xnwyDKeNQH3nCpLTASl5QH3qR2ohEQXAUBAOZRWDfvhnf9G@uAA8NcNw3LYQ1zes7RikMnUiFvQQQ4F1bL1HZAFcGlPn0SGBK71ntfUhJm9PRBJEBKV67Yx6beZAgu61BVWrq19Bdex0TGNociHnWjbN@vol1x0Wl1zIeF9vQcFSApQ2ZTvDnu5AKRmmlCCZyfRHw84mywz2WNLLvlOelJQnS@cmEKdq6spyNntRBoHTVsgL3pJ3Sc6bWkw7ekPdc6y2NJgMu45dYBmDyUbFGZi2kozhSKaTbiupaqjTFLVsVQytY9ltJbkNsliFhJNq2agYdavUKE9FjyYJaK4RDVZXUzFUWQKVQ5XiKtvXLVsbTNibjHBFwhyviSzHYC3ijYyZ9rviHglqZVAuHRQQ0EOa1zPNgZLT8iqqCYSbm28MmJfTKRwiwyWrkUomkqlo1gkD5DSWUaysZ5aDaqs36GIDA0yxvQGobxdl19BBejzU4kNo6tOsRXJNqh80C@nEazPpmqwFitSXI6qSvMph/AwqSoEhrEI@XLxGm@1IhQZlAHV66M1o5Z5zDQkTbdiGgQqxMXH9AooIIvMM1XiGeIrkE8/apQ2KBbG1TLaZaVlQGbDagW4Xsh/JI4CvFjgMYOOVJaKD@voEsBi8TQwrDrM6UKf6oCbcCTNM1D2ghEzesGAiI6qHHhg5aO7kMoViMV7XZqra0M3WMj8CZf0xe2eNwsxHKxUqHNYxr1lPty9G@gXaWTZE0Q3DHAyFwoKceENQSdPtDnlmRCOqeV1p@el02tSYiOY1kgYqe156oknUUcsISyvTA6XKdGErsrblgnrqTaZTB4CrqcTl9wgSI@C9vIAE3xIAITPHpjEagnYDQb7uWkYXZBeps7l@5I3RdPLgFU0dNHymEySNxOSrjwuSlg28kIyFKDJYorN4oJFFVNWYBxV@1ONuzLrXn4PYCUiEBiHiq2V1DWTvHpx9x3bmIAVGBmgRJB7CywEsslO0BqEB880vqqyBiRgUEZQZaA@o@SB/3eFw4JWgvbCG3VFLA0nJnrmTg@GRjcKSHboTa@hwd6vntEA9e1A/s34KWWPUssZTGSK/oAw/eNIVGGIdj1WgBf92BFKnJDseKE7y30HgSJBMCpxQ8F8ZAAlIA0YpHY9U8j4oldOJbSiyRlVJg0onp5mMFVdWwYGxAr7sOH3UQuwtGQho8T1zQXN1QFsJ3U@qX5/b5AVtANl3yaT2wbFs5Sa5tLSULCWroOGXlp6AaxtdT9CVAtcTcmXIhXAauihGmlwYWqcY6NdI3tZ9zGO1gcU2xtbpozVQ9HqptNpI6/W8eBbwqYKqA80G0Bl8AJ6kWqmgU1Xl6jVkVGt14rnfQe18arjWQDDhS/1K5@@CC6vEBqs/cFw0ZMvY2N7Nk37FhdYQjFejq7jJ83ruvHF@c95Ond8m0xhbLeuVFmQK0lP62oXrjKDZVOtrpUy@oar1VWgsW5VkLrmiKJuZHiSkq@oXm2pK59xWkiZobeX8PAlMFfypG12X8I3TBVUNWAV0YAMNtqGS1G42If2W2lBTSYirJtPQ1agkk8AZA5ngUaZRMolB@yCAO6eHsa5e/xLUIzO8HtoUGZebFfCaXeGebXoEplOJHVDLakN7CSRAc9kOuji2Y2fsERnCZKU60YSoM4YQ5IeNBypGKwaDiDvWGCx9qLgT36LBBhiNmh3o7jk9U3tLNobMQPIZ1ldtrllzzNsFzfDCQgQDBpyDnm5AzYyjO5fZOSAEQc1m54eo5RnE0zYPdU/uyyO0DIZuI//aFpnfI8vrInvBRMI@gdsBrqLtDY27SVw7YAY02hfAaXNsDbkxDoJwilFe6J6iovlX4@YTWm3Y5CNRfted2mPHgI6LCU0/hvJeINuzryzXsZHJ2h6gBoktYxlMIZ/HXhCjWu2gsLuYv/OQA8dmvPMR3kaxTjPX8AyWtZ2ec@GwFQBA0dQ0LtgHtgEkgNE2hH4i86yPxKDahQM9mLgMmthee2jk5ddXAzNaR8gswWsfQFmw@ZkOARbk@fTgR3ug4vPFXA7o999y9AkyGcEynUf0NFgIIKotVP2z7siUTKPrMPkcGshClWXb5lUWq5sMLVEXLL0MWFOmS7ZEEE0MQUlDZwRGSdvsWX1reEBjND0bW96wVfFDd0C8QgTHljmUhLkcNsY4XBMqSvuCw@@NUZ96kklP9upod695XDt7UZGzI8/N9qwWlF/bbPbBbuqZnsxYgp2YEFtE@HjZO3GcYYWKBEeGZj8JBPLhD3ebhwfPTmon3/BkKJ5n9Uc9HRPj8Kf07otJZFip4zr9wEb0BG@XV5GbZmwYEDtOInQNQ0diEDDiv47@fRzY0wzpwjBYxuGvgacA3EBAHOzTjMFAukilEJIG/wJPAblJKHEAUHNbvucWegZDfxEzPIpuXvjiSALzTT53i8g9e@QNIjm7yefJ/2rY6WA7EngXyPsyA2jAgOT8PQNlc@iAYjm0PBpnjTJcClqwc0n2m@FYayuHIYWwW8wyV/P783IUEZU9lNalg9Zf6GpC37WIWAIU/cvebMwO6GD6iYHOEDUbwmWu3@rQzxyAkugiQgXCAUvkypc43IW9VAdaRPOawMjYJWTALcvWsyf0QLN3Hj1xAz5GTMvsjKCxyII1gu57wDJbmwTZabWsRaDAFyTdf84Bc0eteWwD47s708djMcYPR@6wZ7bF8z//YRsKYLZ4uvqEGsjA0QS@kWx0FpaWiIov9DO/ZAnmw6hn6cQGct2H0tBxeE3vBY75qFHXsUymq7t9bIdE4YJw4g/UpTvkjFPumr1R2/Sf8xMhFsd7kjy2bfUpR/BEQ4oM4wXRp/rBPD6ZIj1HbxMWbjBYZljavFzMMW86I40sqKsH0Ol3V1k4Tgz9suGI/@LQ8H3lag3wO58rpbiQ5Yp6K29mHU9vWeYdcuDql6O2kxlcXlCmkbT1RdLOKxH2rjKdnn7JnU10zmcAz6JrXVxAr1I8F4Fdd8Eg8AZgUmSv6XGHqPgKm1Grqt@F0@3x30Ug/qxY4FjMJ6tHP58jkCQiBtQaZC1O2mQibLKmGNvTWxPsF3U/X7IwQWoJQfFUjFQqt4qNYjDIF04PDQaL42MTTvG3tubH5jNJhMBwOh3TvK82Q4tk9fVeptCOOBcqZ7/XHrrmgJKlmjF6ugdCMhRsNq@gWOjnLsHFRsZAcQldd4htSI4/lrtoODCMM7AMp2d5A16TxMsiLTk9kBKiwflC@gmj4tssf9tgjmMDnglc8yu6YwxxSG6BHD1AcfHRMBxvjAiG5izineFc43eh6dB1rkz@O78x@ziXqgeooEyPJMMy5kRvG/eJK07u0M98Ll7OpWpo9Ob6l9hLx3G7pu2xgpbzhw9wRF3v9fjw3NnB0WKZ9qye44Elj7938QIsds/jv/OlOco2S7czNEgSdc@PNk2UJrqWC8pU7104vfXNi6wOPwsLfuR2UMGL50MVW6CY8vl7FVNg/zh2XjwXavRL@L9PJmg8xsWB14jzjuZ0nhYTA3aLMwi9BJxNmZ@5/dwmxdSyvHe1qABco3utT/zn79BoLOKu32gMJmQ9g3mHEbY2wTF0uUX9u6S2dndq7Yepphm0G/dlIlK4lz0TFDX9zhQpK@Tynxkjn8s9XFF1eiNzZM5VHEetDyYuTrlDZTycqJzIxrIYacgC83CcIYD6KPqGD6Iam3F8u1PP6D0LKvm9RsxctTcAk3uA3eljcByjYzbihT0axAo3wruTkX1yN@e6A79mO@0YkRjyuRpp835TKWaVeyZ9F1nwe30HesBOH0wH@wHlL5DS0A3/jSEmnxDzBwuHudw78ZZYMEMDZiuYIVCq1qWXwbGyhymewqKuOwFvbUHnzDaHE/xdxO15irTlOL3PKR3Qp20LrTOwOXEp1n2lNGPyiMk6Fg5SeDjg0eosGp7gbY3oRwL3sM@8sKCPIUtDahweUsozY3N3tFqRkbr7upPQYtMYkOcavnsRvSdYufPaprZxJ8HcKnVaZk/nj/H62l34trTVh1hGA9/cpcFaHODlQ7rhBENiSgUNJsAsq53xjK7ZN@n1Dltfb38Yef5jIdDYwe@cYC1Lo5kL4g0sqPM2/saGjyNW0dCxTS871N0LE3spPRzVF76L9Kw/SDqXuQd9/cLcv1e4wkEIXMlBs2YR5/zhiBKfXDUg2j2ahHcAHfvSnHj@c76ZPDGgPEf9O7HNq@cGjnXeW7G17Nyx4XvMPrvrdO2u2XWpcgRvi6oHSOSQr0y9KxNAf1f3LnHpCumksHfX9aLc7Tm93kO4izqRa0jHmT8Mu4drRtsQ9bPwTvQWBIjHvSN20HQTk6gNX1R3uuYIWijPGToDM0Nvi0B7OLbDf@ePLB8cJT321jLdNp@2w4E@fWi1eia7toCED150@mv@uFGr5@i4OuoOIx444z8fMhJlOO59rcKF7gwHA3o0B72RRz80oJvpzB@pLLF9IvQhsmAN@YQpl1jzwmkZXeu@wmuZ@tC2LrOi9ovX@VIe18WUcYtldtFb61nAKneioQxUouGn@DiYX@@tQ7Gu/E57ZGfkupP7dUN8MjAYXOVTAuhYNAwjJnnmBFPLj6sC/NnvO@YlxJzQQoEiWxrt5oyZA@Mkv3BQKLaCQbCgt7o6vIdLhmNc3mtOLBymFPOHyCrDisxygv/0WMbdZLwQ6g06h8qL0YWn3gc/QVNr1@rzle16L1y7c0/M2sU9ksMlANSDbovHXCksHN6PhSZIinfOlZRY/rBZOzq4CxmfLzyhFdrBGj4vLZaWg5/lioXEXrBaP0Gz/LSiz1/hxRK4znCEJTZ0XI0RnKLoqZSqSjwSDoFd2ADmQ9F6aVxDyZdie6xneUOCtTqsXmfLN@NSrpS/ZRUml2TWaHCstJpvbzyghc4nPGp9WW9UlpOZTHI5eW6XWC5JoGbPM@eD6jG4jkUPTmeYdWbrfA0Huv2clvnaUK9L669Bu7VBS74G25pqiuPyFY58Ge0ZzqX9p79ui2XpYEl5rG950BW9sHErhdM3u871E56uSL02GOi4rB1xXHdRBWPqmZ0a865RnfLV6M41e71/tinWtooNH/ByjPU@QgUvVDTrcWHLkBcap6btmFwsRMJBLD9ThtMb9W1ov9rDrqexU4vWrIzccK4eXAhmD11sxNtpdsDaJs5Y0FIkslt7jnNJiwKRkv/013xFLy1IEgtF/ORpRX8kRVx3lKdltIbhjIBqH8lH03UEiIJMBttphL1CEGqT@6u4TIeWGoMkZvyFtpgMX2y7UztlmT2WxB0puHyvbHWU5drJ8zf1XKPyHetnzf/8h1n1RvBN/iKzse7JaeaDlG9RrqLBRQgOQ5NMXh7LIlu494GW@gdCJTY/Keim4vIXzvZp2wTJnXlNC2dpuYeNpiHuRwBt5IHlNFQJNa80lWVlxPsfmdMhK@K2HTDpdXDxjRa0DAkXgWKU5TH7xLooKxkDl8bAG2dID9cd9yvP/Jno1eh6geyu2RrRJNlVQSusVig7y83KdpVcrtl2cB9A/d35uJDLnI839hpZz2fO@fn4i1zha@CeA6bR8uMsVqC9V7s3y1o19@mTp0@YLN8my3w1A9Ty5Zvjg@O907Pa2etT4OYtz2xi33H7eqgpUBZopU/X6dEGC2CLa5ne/doj0CDBG4ArClvW2Tbu2VJVKbrMhUAFq@WMvMydAQj0EaKx74k@L75nRsJnAYRm6lhMaFF2TIIkZCbpRTVo2pctLBes7mDJBRzBtSJzVCHxSGYV4FIGuPRAHrHZXPISfEIeUIz3M@puHPNQAK9CiFkAZFKQFuaXh/PMzc387X@BHA@gXft9c0w47swxQtyVYwAMo1GM/drB4euTvXgkEKdwNx30w1zcQNmhusX35XDpcsQWEF8zURfGE0u9A93qsSvLoy4OylsHW4YeKBesjjRX7qF24QtDWa3ngSZvt0E1tSZD1Gyg0jVaxMRXMmVsJieAWVrQ0KaZLCGsV5ndCgCa69oALfaeR14mOMLsSXP2Lp2b2R/@2V/w/UrnQ3D/RLjHuWfw9qfirQPuf@qH5PPw9s@DtwK8/ZS/vcsiK2c3Z/DcBExEBr45OGYe9cKQRX19HMk9tm3Ydlo29AOsPvD6iliH4DxbIWdCPEr9DXAeigvYjkoa9TKlZ7oNBZfWl7JZNEVw6EyjFTrmmPfBaKX9tyPcaQZNSXa9uL6Wh06ImbnyEdJq2QtcEsIRqmoJpFK6sgaV9y2DbW9vM9kz9J5ZWS9zlmeX9Xer8vuA0GWAlbjVUmcQB6KEMSCsKqIpy3oqr2JUrJzJfJI1ymCQ8BKENk0hB4Co6G37Cy6h0XQEq0A8bHM8JMU/8a0xMIVsWu9n8v2GPqIMIOK4cT/UtJSHizxwTVxE7rVoMchvEewUwUryPCGrv2Pnw3O7IfbFMRCYX84RORvcfzJns1wgPbXZXVrK9B4rzA17emo7uBhoH6hlSiFbWM3m19VInZIFKqAXa9AnQAl1BuqgYVofnIFX29k7@PLo@HRmlxFBJqfBkixZ3U6dZ7R0vRE4klNS7zP12X729OWzfZ@VUarCQXSECEfSp8mcl9o0pQtSf8tX18ymTQEzCeVzD0VMPcHMPk02zWIPQ7MRwB0@@z@TqqLe3NYb29VzOzGT/Kd5OzAT2goKF7jOPdp/mWRzdM6Bv2boDLfUe5q/UrQgh/uLg7Wx/D30XrxPKNigH24W8lcnSbQOOlgGLWkL1i1B3rUsT4p2ynDCfHpB1/ik5pHUMEFDmpkIiVLDRF5mzxIQy30DJh3xjixthNRt6MO4lsGhPVLQvLtLu/agw3MwDPtI0O/C3j91BSfU7QFVEYw/tC0av9Vdf7VuEHJq9q3MmU8PKo5w84/Y9dKFvPWsVlmv1McsWJp71x4YzRv0rKGCG3LGGnYnITeKihnIb@OOlrG6vdUQm4eYv8cnRduEjkfAr2NnwMIu/K7pu06gF8d2R4AcxMBkX476ANehx4mJrYTJXjkZiAx8TPpE1HFjjMiD1m8XIXWta47b1gW0NIqaBpX0RT4fbjDScYeMnQQ9zFn1HBeJRBnzWZuiIhzT67pm2W1zrOBa/lIDuQP@yeu3V0lVnpEB2pklNiq1p7do@cpCH4paG25vmlIIW1uBIojXna0tretJuHQaeiCQ4unQPQQntKFKp68PmDKiPW4e0xi9KueKnfaGrsoyVWzPrpnNUinqu8CDAjRGMTvksno4BKvg1nAlW4FyRl/PbuPjozVg9bymNcBNiahsGUcfdsDcwH67KoFpClFKhBYaYPgrIUXX0EtDivhzmZKVaJcKQM0Npop80aUKCLygXLPq43BTRKQGcq5ubZVEacTV4RYDsdieozEA7Rw159umwF@x@BW4hkoMoHagU2qBQnn6lWnbUF8VkJk@1E6mj0DIXDXtn2WSDre8UwoJTuILsZoWCI1vhd9L3vQcsGeWs2XqAZdvod1/f44Nf0c0/ZPsf5/VsuUbZblXmWTBGFOrynK3kk@trqRSy/aKsmyjOfL4MXacb5fB2mlqsiaPASiz3FPLIM9gHVWW7fKyvq0styuFFYoBr6mUegMRvvOy2s2yfptdfgzWRBp8XF47lWWPdqflNC1/C/RhDVnOpkFmbnCXFp1QgskvW6kU0qAtN5GA77LnpylqV85Ps9RHLwsjN3vR99VI3FYJSmLmZBXOQOFdCjR6ETW6mCpt@sDRjfBzwu60rr/ChSWMBsFNz4vKVzzk4YpFKDRUTkLJKHx7IDBwrAAT8TWtqyook9/@NpFfh17fk/VVxUk9KebKqWQxX04mWOKpnF2RXfnmfDdzxcxMst7Ri9q3jePL4@Ov1XOFbbFkYudIzq/J79hWYSUrJbIruU8b2ez79@/BHGb1qlbVGmo9k2zUFd6h22DVjY2V9PrmSvppshn2IDeYqhQKKhTaOSuy8w1dX0mtFZ7aZQjZws8qy4MTfzfhm2fFItvDz9//@7//@d//jP5@Tt@/tSxr4LXb8HW67JJ9hM9lh@E/uT@2I24d3a3ORwX6GWB@Vqhq5I@TyeJq8vQd7kN9sgR/9A@f4BV/l8hHeBPI7GdJSlSNxMdEPp9PTOivie78ONJ5ztDLeNEnm88XznGf/er60lMGXDVBieKnVHoa4MjKG5uy45BHF1IoMifB2keRVMYZ/EgJ/0QHvXOm4x87a@HfyRD/3ly@ucy8uTwx8O/ZJf69bOHf4Uf8i1C1WUkzIOq7SoUTwwRR05/53prW9F2I5f32@8rv92Gf8xlLCejMJarVRipze1vX3qXKZfEParAcvOGHu4Dexm0ms/2umkrVie56VWRgO9Oo8tzQr9Z8tw1oU9v17W2tWa2Oq5nGu2odc3mDP@Nb/C3IULPOV9BZGW@fcIy7PkoUd4Z/9DnkidSPD6HzcpYubGcShf3aTrpw@vpZIg9vxfAVA1fx9WSvtnv0GqCPD/dqp3vPD97svT4Gf6/RrD59mtJAFJ4CvdVGHUj6IlVNVYbDYfNHzRUN270t3vxtBTRMfZpzXPxVSuxWx6@zmW0g@rC5hRk8odQywIzGJ8bRSol6oq6knqSe5Hq5q1z@Mn/50jkK/4@OxhBgjXMfHDfXzXXzbagyLGe@zk1yk3Gu7xzl2@A04S/XB6eV64zXjtaPno5zFzk7Z@fzMXSL//tHzssjBxA6EG04zg0Rd64Dz4ujo5eArAPJf4A/K5fLjYHOce4K/nO9PH3eNXOQaRU3YsJbLnd@LtWZ/N4E9aflk1ouqa0nk1ajuD749ua2sP5tnay14lajjntuGzJLJ5vn9WSjnMh65@dZrqnlwppcpk25t7fN5m7trNZsZnGQa7y9nHqayjyFT6Wa2haPJ4l2tfzkvJRB8fMFMZHdfnJeXc2gez0F3C@A33Y29ZmfECU8l86lpHL99u1b/L69vrrmLnJwv/O3QSj@vM2CF3ehF3wQNDsvftwxnpU4RakXGze30GCdJ8tJ0aQpjPa3y/nzcaHDCjJ2G5QtFayG/CraputFplar60XwWN9UM0oOuxU8yrk8GAzOZY0GUjRaIlmp1FxXn2DnSVkDJMpWsVI5l3W3eS7XCw2MW8xsrTPHzWytqrKqvstvb0MamERBBW85OZYdN8lubqN/ys3ttkIfFf9UFT1VkBp6VlUFANQivI1vFLatbCvoB14Y7@a2ik6CuwFXXVEb6u0t94NfRd3mWKsqMI6BxfBf6R9akv///L98zTwwPG4TaArbbK2oKq2Jqa6tK5upLfFXWQLGKvJqchVtnKSerNefrqyubKzVnzRWtBX8Ktvn1cac9lYFywcqsl/1KvkEFixqMq18IucLchLdiUTZEDv6e84FW90qYxONEWX4oEtKMijQ6nYgwmH7o1ax/BmVKFMbTL29AbHmgWAuK2LG6fx8nEMFw1RWblWWbxL6bTmBKbBb2QcXtYPwK8kyTUnKN/Ky7tbzDflWXr5p3WK/YiWvkklZXCuXV9a4e2MT3PkVlY@yg@FXDtwQYnq6UUY1VE6g9CaBkWriXKq0zAvAB7kdRCtoqlgsLmUL8Bh/sb5XGK@IT3VlzmezsJlaST2tr2xtYXk0yPPTklTGCT8@uyhnZF7L2eYWUZHAqQn8bJvLx2BWiL@V3RXuyuN3b8mTBsyGDudGjrWdHm5dczqdJfCEbj1rmSb0rMxezz/9ATp/vfa11TaXJM@ET/9YN0emeT0aXZvBZ8fy9A8f9AF9xp0ffvnjH375P/7wq5/@8Ksf//Crn//m@5//GL5/Dd@f8udP/81WEX9/8/0//99@@Mtfgeffwvc/wvc//Ob7f/mH/Evvfwff/yvi93fiG4HjXwlw/elvvv/ZX/3m@3/6C/j@K/H9xfT3hz//t/z//xZ/6PzVD3/@d/gjXn78Uyi9f/ibX@L/z/7mH/7jL/H/f/9f/@Fv/sU//Om/JsdfcMf/86/@Df/99R/9@Nf/@M9@/UffL/j98Z2/3z/A//v/Cj4Pp/MheB6Sr8/1@f53ouf34UaYCsgASNqf/PAv/xhk9c/52z@BN/gPgn4SvMRC@MtPwhfA8L/MifQnv/n@z/4qePvjOGAsDJD8BML@Mhb2kx9@@Yc//NX/8MMv/@KHX/4pKpzM2la6ls7k77buEwBYfAAcAq4/BA4AOcgSW5IK9MQf4cmWyDVekYqr2AnK8E@Ke35aRtOQnX@SivCe@pTFcztY9pMIPcfdI3kIXV2j0BxYuTkMLeKrHxohBWeLnzyNGd@ckJVPTxkAQ@QIMAE@4YT6/p9iWhtjUvhSQDh8w8SWgvhLcxjzhD2FYGjhqJHbxl98AZ9n0CMTHbNKdZNVpDTbrLAqe4aAFXincHTSO7SHeDRtRdplz7Arid67wCHeL4YO23vs@KYIvMpBWVVi3xE@gabCEX0ngWeKv@/C8zsBPZYIG/4L@xLd@PUD4CfFuB@8YqNCeMSPxCF4MPMfUV5iJxjhMN4Y/1mISOBJScCGVDrabwqSSIVeUvCamkkloGcqLBWGMdE2xlCl2AzCuwJj3tJ0RDYXi6BgYehUNv3QOSn6oYnZKEFQlEGpVJxhGDOeqZSUwlVpKyLRldQKLUJZ@dyPoIkSmMuOOz5Rfq@EOY/iDakPsRK9PEKKYMO0MUj6ximVKt/l1zYkeNL7CA@DEscSgQTiSb/aNnwQunqTwYoqVU/3ziDs7IjlCzmN1XONm7WNwlpxrVhYXV8vbhTya@tba@vFzdVcPreeKxYK@a21ta3NrY1bqfo1G2vs@PgPMreAaJzJZAuIkVXyxY3ypAIxyUuq4pRBhZtxk5sMWHBIwTlZkDc4s4@DITc0/vUIPkx6JLFH4AWfzK3ET/QBGq8xAzSLxMQ808FRWcxG4Kl2fEZCzhe35CmOq7iXUjo37TZPTtpgr4/h5@Tg@YuzyPNsr7bzQlpnz45e7U49igKoyA739s@C1w0e6kctBii@2Ts8nH4VD7Rul1hxI53WNA1@8JmmDz215Xc@SF5b3BjJ67nChpxPNycmmLg3mczthdUy8@vQNVmTHyfAssajqqSXuHJgK8@XfFoerm0D8Gublha28CzP0WCxJzzQC52uddEdsuG1EwB4nncddPrf@j38oKf/lrV0Hb@f@4EEzOhneLfHkKdBfjMhvVlw6QX0C/p4ZBVuaxjicLXVYTlJQ/EsFLY2i5tbq4XN9ObW5loxv14spvOFdH5jc2Mrl87n8pv59c3iVj69uba1ugY1AUKLWxtSAoTL6mSzUCvzskxPyzbwbJVtPKTG0bpVKdE2O7gGko2VtsoS7cBjtMnk1c3zHIOIsoSrkVbGFbmwhuu0VvMsL0uyzgyW2N/fye3vy/IzfMHhpp2cLLfxpbiZy208k2WTQnagthYgUhff9tZxXEqWLXzZqe3vI4YP@FLYRByyfMlD@EvPf9kAMBtfVlcRAZPlbwN0OUDucIo2KdaQv@Ryz3ZkecTJ24Q/gKvxtzUidg9fMAAj7fOQHQiT5ed@JDCMZPmEw4mkXvj5rdVk@YC/1GqI4kvKfJFn6it8qdEHIrnwBoIryxfguHChzyfLLXCi@MqyAS5jooNfH1y4kcse6rI84fnAnMjymKB141KWm74/pAP0vHihd4dt84J/Ji5/GhB0AEHWeLS333r@vHVx0XIntb3nJxT05Zcv9A@Tkdu6aImIrSZ8HIwFQZf9yfTHxKBmU@/ND/oKguypoOakaRKFTf1boEx8LjChfvNLDPoSguZNMAiE8OkDcAs/z/rwfKa3eJD/oSB6jlstuYwii1Wno5Dg6ml60Alp6g3DeWJP0Z@QWiqhSnI6Si492lQzxSejTXl9Qy6twFN@Iq@CE6oGyyVzjMnJc1lW61uNJ/JGUS4lnzzJJB/nnzB5Y0suyRsboOLV8i1qf0W96Sjj9LiSA49sdhsrNFZBeAZNj2gZCpsy6Enw9gF4zQ/qLjQToJIZfDMZCcMHFUGxzBQ8qBHXW9PkoZJMbhSSSTVZhrhLMtAiSKEl2Zhln2IZdAZQvFWA6K45HLk2y5VvZ1J2L0veUHdx9phSKDF5Hdox8MbTL2c/T6HDki6ttIrb1X808/nv/tG8z3xf/Ei8bV7PS4lbqY1nqaxtlaXEjXR7c7td9ZP8ik0mesrvFbDHjF2klqXlJOY8uRo3hGuV2sVJzR@cqu1AZ2zVWXMSy8vLUmL7rCqvykdaMxiKrmZpduMcpz5wmkA7b24vpX6nceqMVn3qT@wA6VnJNXEtdRtvF@DjxZtFLIkL5iVSv@MHEpEqgFMq4yCfnMDqY/ScEc6@sXOeoe3vEjSezI5vOiObFtOUXqKxouilUzrxqt4AGf7uldW72VzNVGkOWAERviWpMI5ofk5K2I5wAh@d0XBojocK2DhFtHFUKK/B6da7jXeb716@Pnp9tP80V9osbRLTz8@FoKTzyXySivEptFXWyd499mkTDMtPTjH/nf1lOVEaJFfXkqtB4HklwbkIbqwbSr2eb7D6aqNRB3lsMBVeK5XCk3xxM7VWym8wNVEtbGiePkk0xD4UZW1DhRcaYSzkE2/jn@vYyxVNhkmJzZfvP9GgHz8h3yqQK5tlbPl2@xb@q7f17e3bbVzRCQ/85z@3tzyc/jED/gs9wk8MLoQJw383adSaicZ3mW3@v40/O0ecCfJ6UVYT7ytVkJF3zXfNhJTYYnKByjWV5aOMA8a40bJi05/preDfu9BjBYywleDN3F7xWLEKHXXwy2az5@ofFMCi2dpa31xPSL8Fdt2xpg5Cg0UmHdN0vVF/3iqTmmu91HEFjh2sNAHHy9FHPAL1qX8Jgm/8MLR@cBkVmj9RP2ERRbzo7pC438TL4pp/9JUkdFl0kQ3rkOThwPuQ1m6zFdzYiVubVOlGegS4RsaQtgvAT1mSHuG6dXxVfLg0e@wNVRx7yKnSo0dCMXtDzRs2ETlGEp6ZfFm6lZA9ervtMTqEGOeL@H4oHVeBOwN@AkJvwngkj@oGt@RoKxOmGyF4hXU4FZCbFUYpEuWYOZ78Iw7WGnWQlP2Dwz2IAx2dDq33ELFlt4VHdFP2ljoqC9oX4AGeU1sRnCJwBAR04MkbarWPm64MhSBTLI/hHVo3AlBplk8TJWnWERHr@NqA6Ii@A@rOA8Q8dYXngK00RbIiD4IeygSwEHNHzSQ6dPfCSIvSw0MC6w2V3fhbOxQMZdusEO49EbigMPj1OhTR6LfFccOVkM2ELd9IQ9GW@RYBJYATPiGjbqWVYbpf5kU1KEtfKQbYE46rlL/rP35svBvU@42y2q8M8ZlK9aHpvlQsDrIyrPQrIB6DutUoD@uplNWo9NWvFHzHU72xnRdWkaeKvEHO7QrQgutwPDX9sW5nvrMb6f26nQKSR@mVH1U@pvVKDu2ZtFXJp3vpbyt5kQ9Ic1j5mLLL@jZ8ce1UbPsFWCspvRzzwiiXSq/ysa430EDqQcRUah8yA3R69V4q1VAh8R4EzkYs9x4/1lO96rjcy2RUhHq3@mS/PgRHI1XB95Kib4@ffKyPIH5JgWcFkumpQDzEE7y@DWgH@srAY16mIemcRrLfxkBev1JZ@dGTlR@tVJaWPtbHmX4jzdlfyoXSgMSPkfhyZHuLsvIjlU2xhKbQFPkLq/SFBspRTlupFDA5PYjE5BSu/AhCBqmUT/Ut6ku69MNfl4cSJrZk8BN@6fhRWmZLxyx7dFr5sI2b0yBuzTMsS4DzXYUDCzrSOm7uTdNR3jpBYJi4hQgDz8dPnkh@0mIXAKSMyqVlMh075HQHhYvzeXSjFd/HfJ9@naeGfZ0b9ETpWGno866uR6orqSaqcJ5r1BEE1cBN7rbMNRbf@wHKhrQHwJD2QLgMahFkktATArIiAqG0/AKCWKgnOnwPPp5e66F@Qps7qPmgQjgZUJnnkGGlP1RIN4E8WeBi1jalBw6oKtIjyATSgHmwGqwKiow9fszE63aF5Qsb2BYgGMJ9SOURaIZSSPwBlAIOpPIDyCjqQ0oEaHuEIbi3KZbQ2u@XkNiaqECE1Ic036Go0Q5FZWR7fGMu8k3lZGBZPHr0IVVZEwTBP3VZID6E3f42IZr7Ets5enn8@mzv5GXtFH6hC7cZPa3fvxFn5h6MAd5v0bJs2p9j6Cd585svDcYUsIeHeJYoXnjVZl@@PmSFwqvdNB4BBqxP8KFKaFBLASbTo5OWPc1xL7LX1qWVjV@jh3cT0VYgurQv4x/rj@RQ49wLtwuHu4U9HA2DxlycWxQ7Qb9vep643iPjX5lGp0bQxuk@7v@FWiiuA6FV1v5CUVqWjJPOaVrs7loXFt2D1eUIYvHpYPQhj071Q8JrPNr6UEeJlrY2c7kSy6XRkfcdBd@x6jvWfEfRd6z7jg3fsek7toQj72POc8zQKV5dXQ@dG6FzM3RuBc61XOgMMawVQudq6FwLncXQGaa2FqS2vkl4WcLnJlVd08Ww/NqmH4bb/aFXhJ5FQJOf9lwDQgszkBB9bcYT0tuMe25s5URCB9kjBCoU1sN30D4@bEXhVKU5HWmeMn8TntBWSbz/RwK757qglfbGeG8RCJ1aYrj9UZJA7TKjZ@pgDJhDsFIq@yD/plrixwK4k1K4BRIxVPLBO0THY/MhTp6u4OLiMye4MC@YYyvMxcbPVWABYyL7RwWRnMpSrKXlGNdiflGsS6hgkaMLIAocAssgvuHUT/PMHc1NcvXuJGMI5yY5QxTHW5wXC3mjEPKKH5Xaf8JW8dPjdopJpQ1mgLhwkWRgqkDxfIjKTb4k/@b7X/wf7Dff/@xX7Ie//NX/@x/@Z3T/W/z5d2CzsEIA8NOfMZo9h59/wWiunObtw0gEv1qSf/jFL@H1f/rX7Icf/4wH/dlfyem1ABGEoFcY8@f/BH/@GH/@TzldDAB//iccEKPI6VspZlopAPXTv2UMUkMsAbJf/DVjcgoMDEVIXp3X8UZkNzlHELChTq7GdDj/xetqgMc5NSUDXvGWD99SWABqBLmr4w2CYd0Dc4bPGaGWNnSjizuGhZfjof1joAnjeNoFyNt1G4weMdCRhNz/ESuxZAphVFw63cY@DulwkX@RbzkMRdiUnAXq8MoLgYou8wkoge6tBPJNPYGJp2G3hXqkeS4jgr@v8IZSvwGRfcmiu00kkZYfG0dixD1vdNmN39VFocVmiB8rQXe8SGJLaz6SYEzdTBUbpDLtA13GcKN5NCp5mP0BFAlEC/iNjMUX4kJ6Gl1YcqLa7B3tT1UY/LTAxLyMaqQgoQqT5XtgkdMCXkWLazUOz@kVAPVcabUR27Y@D1j@@uuvZSnil0MZctsKYYhkiquMICgfDypEggqRIKCZ4yRdUywUpmighgP1YvyIBh4toqLi0ULhwprjlwOSAX1BPlKa7vRGXrcyi5o0clzZzSKPoMw3KqKenNukc6pMVmciAM54nMp0Wc5HnZuBmS2o@TGR2zGfWGktxhSLE6kUxD1pmktByeW35pVcPME7UOcbqQcmVMj9ngllHpjQevH@hKaLFePG0C/m7/1qx1cTgYYPkfGKn4g1UNg0/gJEL1RHSLFLTkWFLk9NdHla1w5T5lzoB/5Z/8zP2C1@buQkUOzEvHKGJh8eeDpwoMvhoBUcuQZ43j3f4tbdC9txTS96HIXFN@zaSTwQxXAubGjV0nj2qCWuqMTpeX70VbxdCVo2YYXu8JuFETVnFFqezaZlW8NmE4zPXkcNGYivmoG7KJMSXkkMrkh8JTBtjwaKg2coD9X7cZK9y6OdWcalcjQQgUlIpMagQ2eYPeh8sS5eVuY5nCWYRX59GVikraFCB511nb5zYdoOngWDsafQH4S4kSB9MCBa0kxPMyNCkehEK0ZaV0XUrz47KvuqgNft@fELcQQxZqSZO81j5Kw7J7nmwuR4ND@908@n9zRK7@nd9HYs1xtO00yeONqDz89LelUJMQBgSMbq/WSkxfFPM@TESAm88aJMHuHBJLZNz4DmDymtAWhNgGsdkI908ObRfklB@JtF/L@7AP3oew8tPjJmTyegb/p0rx110Tw6/M42TAXAD1Q1XA8WSS4Q7d0HpiU6OtTDSzOZFJeNm3GhYg4Gpu0Fi6t8xPfIPK4bmpF7WkxU4YFzaHKv0uyysLiIdptts6dPzLYiINMRvH6OT0y9TfrqYRlHRUdKz@G3oyq5dD5mitGhCQRUWiAyevpKVReLFQexAumhyTii8GAx/2jgblo14yBohc@BOC5o0ASdq0an2Q0mgwk/aKXHb2UXepS3P7wkX@H5M/cyBPjAbw/Mp8Nk1bvU54kSZOkBLUIAq8WzTNuV/WbLAWt8pgw/j0X355RGGYJIFb@UY9bJohK37irxiFT4MsmtkoeJ5H1C92CZi4gaRxaqsJ3Pa0JmMO/ovZ5hKFGM3OfOEnPsGZ2Aflhijr2gVWnOUahBTNJ0Q7z6qcLtC1WywHkAzyt4voEnIoQ@aJMLlJ83tGv9IS8K6euDiNUifOoG2qIRLqrRecQIlOS7cSD3NkjTWJimMZOmEUszqAHxJCNAkhFLUpQCFs9dRdAzO8MF2hmDsOcOj7vUNnxsR3dx7vUmaSVLVpolr5IlUMhJM1naU0ApJ9vJ0i45vGTplByXydJX4AjrVvJTsuRXCwRw4ZUcT9FfqHB8N5KlHUW9lfB6ds9PV0uWgjIFmCf8lThyy4dXW2LW3wlGVU28@haNyjRDifHg4WC26o00fXPwT6DisFIIXKqwwgoBYwck1mhEWgyeDjQbGl5e7Crzmo@SPzQlxjfCMRQIT1UigyooJSPSR8lEMq6MOGEYSoOP8AQCUW@W5lPE8jM9s/vIEalbeOkwMDuePnFPI3ugrVB4HYCjgzi9ML5fXnEUvAAfRidGXkTnDDl@ckQRLgZQ55CFTH2fvCNTWNZTB1/y0o@W0OwYARZixgfhpURoIzodbDi0TSmxgTOICwmF4myfFY2DH1EpUXqnopFWEDVzQTB5i5yhYohWfvWu7ETiIWkxFYSB9VyD17KgXSBdjEGhrotYqrzyAQkRndOmk6hMFNtd4SQ4rm7S1FYsaob8uDxJ0lxxNQmRNdzrPdKHPPVwXgZ3gH9e99WPCSY40IgIIjGDVLh@dT7Dfne4/e4b1D4TphKYZ1jPb0pnzes7W9kpynthsrMFiIFptqvONY6CFEKWQ@8gYpnfJWszJj7eEsqNfJ5ogH3K2vfZFvQJ7uHbdN@C40Irwb2Ke17iwOxlYTGjZi2S3pXmGy0apiTw8IwHlIZZu5tWnvF5RYwh2EbD47ML2I0XcLTwEB9lwJ1iOa/luM2G5imCuk3nCYUzF3zWwcFVYsExrhFPUPe0fi1YogUeR82T3aNXh99Ao7uxsaHOTkVgrYW4YTsu3TlNEHRbCmk8iQ8PD6a1E13HHS6d2/LskjLyAGNAp3kbLn6ijqtCl0X0@VTdhXgcNsJRgesyrAZ6TCuhqaNjk20JvvI7aZQVXSDxzVvgd5p6azhrhNKBEzrNJjVfzSYuzmk2RSuGRRNMI/02IS6pLYTrNaREfDUTWVzezHFXOAAwwqUV4QCcOMiKr0NJAJ6DoR87iDWyh5a/2AHHh3CKKlgZoazmcXTioBP4EB24KEMprGEXtlDEozN4LITGgU9aWinSWeKGDp7n7g0cm07kpVMOyWzH0@U9f@iVyB7Z1zotA@Gp0IkfEYr4gix/Xsyx@VHrHo@Lm@ZoCNnnTZqZFxrN@BS2oMtxaQ34Qa3B0g9PpUhEMK3RAh63emYfSDoF2Z0zmvzSglLp7lsXFyBIWXHREl/gcqZD1IzTyez4B5Al2Bu9Z7X9o7DFmjA6hl6MAwM7ldgJch4rrIM1tZUGzoZfYCwuk2F4SlyOFmkRFHw34LHBnZvpSNwlZaLGn3n/oyK@JaWJJct3E1suXqp0pdsRPvPNxtGhaTFpSXogMnPpn1kmicMrKzRPqeEatYEiJ2T/MDN08mUTes/wz1ZT8FS/kvTIJsWDK8CYwdfWgIFro9FG02tqsCTVZl@w1QJdGw/pkZVKyQIOPrMXww5hEBWJ5av7hIKRv2jLX@BkovQogbqQyxrG90UZ3XQodijLbEmg4xMqWJV5FfBfipGXVehqPJqT8JIipwBLSlblGCaAF7Mfj7jmnY0KShHUw@cuxTZd1yYw6QpUCaMbMsUy4vIdC3tpZS8uH4yt68XOVHShZkesX@PXyqTl17gCq8QTobZDw7MqUXWXp3V3Ju8v16QHrpNmK7QjtBNraGQXIwdkLFn2XQRQi0ISinqGln994ZXgCzSkfZTAJlqxoBBv1HtpI47gOmrc@59rlCNNipKPUoMEdjxQKB3gZ1r@AletPoaI1MRCe6fOM5ty5Vh8IM4b2LSSW85oMkUVq44RUxwFL030D9a@SrTg3Vdcd5y@rWfzm7n1LVo/zez0MN2vbzXSK0ZFZubQ0u2@N3Kv25cXTvcKjAU2@NAaG5OP3zJWXGO4q6TwmO9wzq9XsnR6zQadAbBFB94s@wcM0D75c5kx2hCL5xkkGQt2IpWXmEqONP6U5PKMlLKVvi@FfBF1v77eqNiVXLlftxtlO5VSh6nKMJVPKejxOK@WQdPyYZf6sEGrIrMr7KW/dBHPpsSxVafDjh3b6DpJj9HddNE5Pdpf5legvj6I1qcr6HU4btSng/Kk92MVcdYLW2F9Kqbl@HDDycBE1Ris@uzhxZ7482i0vlaeDcccPnqES5TLwjaNZuBGGoxaPcsAHUT8RBMDlyuWSmLRvcFQbkFBoZ/FPTkt0AIpGFz2Qw1nMBGRLQ7S9POyHUFZVbDtUtMPgfShWiCTTTxJ3AUwDsLZGwNngJqaHpVThe5D0w7aGdwnoZZxFTlb8sP8HRUIj3JD@xqaYP7RLgh4bDMBSmuMmSpW9JJv3cJFBWSqVZM86NGHUX9A7bvG6RUcwWtSmgPdcoOYmjfCS/QUlkdmWD7RWALouMUde1dgWEaLxi8LHFigyW3MD@I7prNugWBDxzu@QDfi5A7iazsU5xG/h0eBRpAPXHEyRFzKhiqKGhiHZ0slB8kSo3GGMnhRk1OOhH6AUMzrguA@BPf1YXdBcBdxj7xFwS4E4@08C4ItCOZrTuaHOxDOLakFAEMcRQNxbQ6d5lC3egpfMI1LrW@5wlZYKuUzNhABxguGl0c8PhNLz9kSLx0ubDHxgvpJYsUBUKQVUXnwPZQWCsWDExQuF5E0OU/YDbs3MTH4BCxuUkqgdjF9dSWGn0UIgPoHqpTNhvuJ89IOMhqTHw2anQssbWDWKvv06S7KhCDG5S/f8KWPlxCOc0ZyyLkV4uGXh4TlyiN9FJHmxxFL86PazbdBw3z4lbIQqhBet8J63bHAXoSoKlo5oTd2KVX2JPSpew1WCrRHyEdeLe7nY2FGerDHSTUyzVqh03g4V3WUe4ipQ4vcCpUF7sPSyzPs9ALoTBy6CtABN6fkzIjJjKiln5vZh@UmAfRRpSbelLmiNcA0rAoC55Cn83KN6gSObDlZ4v541YkVR2YtQMb3KzYBwXAbaMCWzVfjfpto2Rpf8wN6PldYS9MQPge5DdnkK6uH8Om/QOVCxokme4Snv8dVEpvDmhnwIN/Ir@p0lZvKHtf08zNX54vGkk@SSCOblSeSuifQSpZYjgUbY8rs9n499Ltx5iYsvpi94ymLdYVf6L4kPkQEbxcw@l4hi2eh0GAxjo/onujBvU0SbfKc3yiFUxdN38cf1uJ1e6EFhlSV4@FIM0foB4ChHI2VFjZXNVSdYndrc@gbN@nQCqPry0kqwGQvS1F1jt25fWq8o77B1hziSDQEVwqihen6lFkd37YFM9iPpxlNLGbOZOQn1OkLx2krvsEkDAbC4K@ABqA03y4UmFXcvAyTh@SE0csuxCpqv90tg8@S8KJ2BTzQ@BSyiUSsXFC1KWO1idg3lkd3AlE4tkaQlD@7g4NBXPuw0rQ/Qgcm0KO5kXyNj3u@aGew0PPUEsfUg7yj2zjwRuc4Udd6W0b/oCAQpgod7XD/MJXB7ZxRBr5HWuwevol2XayypaFNHBS6P8qklgNqtrdlTCY8lOO3iaXsyHPpAlLTvmJ4A7iUYKbNT4Uv4c2KmU0ciMWLEYU2oXFvGuQBMYGSwtQ027xWxOWJuEtbViW@548GhfISHh1B4/I986oNVj9fET9wvDH9TqCzkNNGg6FDISIh2hvIPlmfwv3qOZqlFT0GQc424QlhFJy/4b4TPhaVyXMDKY/HYqgRFHWMSQpXPpdlLD8kVIzX1RuSp5m60UUiUPY@8e4UFBdJ8q3k@UWPe9mQFTg5CM4eX8U7oLE5TIKsE29C75B9fM@jg/vQECLKveinSDTgiiE9xxmgkONQG8bfBgZwxj86PdvdOznRxKGxfEYAZxH4ODEuwaANgeLiUzFMirMBuB2TF8ojzCzi5ulVQuSkf4lHmKxgE1aFa2Qn5xXu9@Q5yOTpbSYbAbzKwYklNJ0s3jzkZU6smh6AHYW8C6MpkWgZP5oPHGHFo3u5oRsGLrR9afYdoHiH7knPc148CtmBTuSIn34qSN@rY5qNgHgenpkJz8TCNR7OiQqhNKPrhkClKJCcuAnhbpkcgqVn0qowyPTBK9q9ozluhO7yXbCeBp00KwSuBkXJpTII2I4FZCIh7@aUPg9ZisUJBDwIr/NwId8FUfIBlTHYp/H08SmJAjJpjatYEjIlpZpt9fhlvGEIaViG21Z4dCxvEjteKcWAiFAnGVATeDMpVttqJcSSyvsah@qMXN1@KmtiSOqJMk2Gyu/vnK5Yc@pIhEuUZooYN6aWBNKh4KUICsKJgsb8mlv1I09E5EkELUIt@clK/k7seAWHrE1X8QoOm3/CH7@yx4nz4RLzAx9xysc883wmK84gUrpL8nw2xbXJ0B2Z3FNk6o5WJEx7Mo1xvpJ45WAP1OjSBbR@miafb@s4I7u9FOiJqKLwNcUM34MQwekQIO@L76IixMBb6bfZFem53gersGeOWQ1tap0OU5Jik5l4ZayHJ0RCBl3mjQaDniX2zbFrmi7j@cwXijjZE2KMGA2adIALcDh8Gl1i8hEiaewIMV/jOo4wwMNLhOnySYa3W4Fq7ViAcqhJNXvC78XEbWYFPqVospHHr5Gm27IjRPCS47UnuGtUk/yJW57VDq/f9hBMIMi44/JLlJ1OSZL@YGQZlzvPWSGX28jnVvMRlvlD1TltdS16B3IQUMjlc7lifk2SdpzBhC8dUQwVca1lEGGaHWJD/wZk07zC26ekGrQYBIjnSXqme2W2NUk6Mds0BtwaEUdQlPE6ajqlgvbRow/YVnieEF7Q6qX5LawgYfjE9pmfDWDQwuW0hHO0A9PtW0M@k@tc8Xu4/XnpjoO3htNANE4Jc35gpL45BKasqCxOEu37F7SQ7ULb8YEburgkU285V3ROh2AD2KkWHm9EE6wSblJFDNHE@A17EUogPaOnW30UpzkE4C6WkAM@AZC19sgw76RBIiI@kwb/9s@2Y9D15rpfMlnQfg7VFajupmuB9g0ZTKVC0SK0QwGfvTg4ZadH@2dvayd7DNzHJ0dvDnb3dtmzb9jZiz22c3T8DZ2Lyl4cHYJ2OWW1V7vg@@rs5ODZ67Mj8JBrpxBTpgCp9uobtvf18cne6Sk7OmEHL48PDwAboD@pvTo72DtNs4NXO4evobF@nmaAgb06OmOHBy8PzgDs7ChNqfrRpDAeO9pnL/dOdl7Aa@3ZweHB2TeU4v7B2StMbB9Sq7Hj2snZwc7rw9oJO359cnx0uscwY9LuwenOYe3g5d6uBulDmmzvzd6rM3b6onZ4OJXRo7ev9k6Q@Fgun@0BlbVnh3uUEuVz9@Bkb@cMMxS6doB5QOBhmp0e7@0coGPv6z3ITu3km7RAerr3B68BCALZbu1l7TlkTlLu4QqUy87rk72XSDRw4vT1s9Ozg7PXZ3vs@dHRLvH6dO/kzcHO3mmZSYdHp8Sw16d7aYa3XVDSgAO4BeHgfvb69ID4dvDqDNqM18dnB0evVCjkt8AYoLIGUXeJwUeveG6BSUcn3yBW5AMVQJq9fbEH/ifIU@JWDblwClzbOYuCQYLAxLNoNtmrveeHB8/3Xu3sYfARonl7cLqnQoEdnCIA4MR039Yg0deUaywnoIs7QVglX3LTVJzsYJ/Vdt8cIOUCGiTg9EBIC7Ft54XgOdTlrDR3yu3OCbzZWT4xFHL3ITw7R7t7YPHxw/rk0P81NDqb8cm7WBg0NEEgvIpZUGqrmm288b6JN2Nj1zyIxmew@95FGk@9VPF2knPpjrMBxUQ5RUgkms03tSb0c0@bTTX9kJgxMu6LIXa53wWlijz2HL1N3fzY2FKUUdXH4iydND/YIjrW8jgYfFBZNts2RTRcHIKI/WEicegTIGujZqRVI7rNIknSFHN8rIhOJJseLPKnNx0PfuxP4QtvGyIeoJz5uoVsFvuwRAaeLMcC@iEROnRNnLxG6wCsDiWpeaZ5eaHkoslhl18MUKl@HIIdQjfwQlHvid4yL6aiZ6bjE7G4loeMFf@4Hf8YHH4tKb4JljFRLppLOVP40B49VJ8aSgiMQpUnRQuFxOoT5TGPjvu3@VihWg6OaqHj1l7Wvj54i525XGGtPOX/IvDndQtX9eHZgdDe1Slegx4vGhwAKpiF3S9giTXhU6rZbCQOWGVkTwbAeBZQF4GurTa0qdhUd01q1vEEIn4cQzQ@NMauNY5SD2r4@Unt5bPX@/ugOZHatc3ixnpZEicaucOv0/z5DaZDR6Qjd8GKvrbATKOgSC3ZAbtnf@YwwsjpiVh6CIgnfPuFRp54LWuwM5nbCPz8Mj4MhNn18AQnGw8xk/EQJlfmFw8vSb68zq2ZQgCUWFZVzA3eLo8Wvg6mEsmAwXch9yZUamP8QdxB9fereJAhIUBCxMz@YDgByYXOBek9ed9f0El9G1q2hSCa7MvxQPfXIHHGoM6kVa64xpHehGxHShHsWixorK9U7BQTiFiapsI/BI@OtIQkjh3Pr8Hc0wKfr4W8gfMbcfgiBuFRWrXhKbBxP4iZ8Q9H5GPOomIIzI1qBYro8eMgpW2GA6mqIIqP/8eP5ovWBiKFL2hgU4j9lUcBn4MQGoR@mlTZDZdUPDUF8ZSFxIp3kNx52RFYyv6RM@LdP6GPcVzhgX3kdR2kIfkg3/ggATtjbPq9@EH4/xvyZA7@behwAvaQW6SHLXtkPpCThJXzCnqvxBTr2l8xFlmmFnIz6vVNiOY2WjDdIGNiGd6YTywBC0TpTHyPb/iRrcocBqCQ47hGtP4GN5p3deg5PaW6@4jP9Lu20R8o/oGnflMxg7eRJpsr7S@RwxeVT@HnWCS5Qzy/7intoyWdgR0u0GKtCfvCkzmOVJ50DmY6u0KDHkEtJ9FENuT9Gh6KU05ULb/yj8UKo7CVafuht2CKLj5MNZgOwTMbYwrfnwHxFQitfYpmWLAN0qwioXPzjSvpaZSfiVYcTycHFUjtMjuj5c@e3qE@MzZFYq0yLorGJBHPF21xJmbLHF5jc9Hj2GmNdoiNKV/QMnFMRIxFBmaEr3xVDbhOjex1QD0NU6K8BtS/ti9tvNzC5ENcPoQWO2EzusVdYy91Omyz97B8y2HiKWRrNZ7@gU3r1g0@X4lDc9Rzh1Swp/@FF3IELM5rtC6hHQq5pBuX6Cn7MmpdZ6wxPCitjMi5f2Yk9BnoROB5Rv/twg4BysrUGlgmn9vBIFKJN2SVL3zzBV287gaub9AlxpkrkCkgDnxwwawwg5BktJtwkeZsbSP6YtsWcPFpCSyn62utpY/6ut3R@1ZvQqtOPzhdO@vZI2@AF27LshwfDcSDVnAJOtA@NNlby2471x57BtUBB5JOX70@PY4P/EVGvnb4yBdjX0Ia7BmlLM2g7@CeFM/pDKFozDKbiLt23HC4h8YJxUgLDWtN0AM3/rgkQJBuP7CMn796zZ6btumCPXhMay7ZoWWYNqgPMKZoFabX5ZoGwfcx9VOROttH24VGdsrMtGhQJxjbk0QCAlsaRUuBqggEu@LYahybn4CoR8YEtdkMh/lq@4NKXWcgdlvgoCkam3yIszPqpSU8G/vtwdkL7IzzjjmNzUCz5o/14VgiN536fLAWMuPq9nACTJGmB2@A7PvGbjRGmy0Ao7SYndSp6@OdOG0c9ut5kFW8KEloAWpBoKqa1hUexkvDcA8pI1pnK4bNQr6Vxf7VND8e2FcdsdKTwtJL45nsWpoVt9iZibLLjnu6AT0sdjrC6KurYAc@c7whgr6sMZYr5PP5TH4Vh2hfn9Y0qgj49U9olaSDl8dHJ2fASHEEkS8YQZuJzKdDUflqLGBHBo9Ghdy/R4Xsw4PGLLwn5qEJ7p@TIJf5jIVckqHsDR2HeyGHXtwcpiFZHJJ3XDqYFXfbgAjFqiOk6l2j8uVTI5RSBHuajob17yynpiWgk3ZLUoT3SFsP5KqH86HvKTL5gQIwx@QHsVzqGbTFsUJQJn2zH1BvDf3WXecA0vSZsgHD@FgqCEcynUQrCbinRvG0TVwj4eHpTH3vynBBt@hXIHK4hMXfcgQyQ7pJDXKjt6yeBXUA6DK6DjY4XF35BUFDENETZyUq8eAsQ2yQiJY5p0FB7Wo7/QCUUyVJwWY74T/wJobDEhfQzcaeljcwzTadRDUa8KOWMFyDWt6DloNvwyuFZzBJiRytm3RB2eCRd3R9F@7Nx72ULV7mkp8bkCp/@@ZZF7v1HBHk6HRIlRRPxFXm9LDTDOd5VSp2HQQC46rIiAUbKQHFII2TUkAVlDcJBLlIXNK43adH5T29zxIj0mGP3iAegLj4rK4ZD/DRY96FcwaAC2klIGBqC6dPDN@HxN2xMbD4C@YX153ipjSF5xEyN1EDZu5beEQ5Hxtw2IWDvwis@Rzjc4QmzRHObAzFuwvzgG8aMj8LCVDBAW0RyMIcnJm5OFfn48wInGKy8sC@og1xGIvEgueCn7bhgH5ERoTZf@74qpe27fUcPsEU5P6i57TwXEzQFJAaPibpsGCj3tQDizE6Gso3acbP89z2syRIF3ubfNuFbUP9MKts2x@xqJ7bvKBEQIXXJdoTxqjtoupETvwRNYqccuxwULQ6pk4HRfK4L@huRCsLlMJHLrGwZuJKnCi8SDkepR@Lkp@KIoiLR2nFohSkcCf4VOliDFT9@IznzLdLaFUSlQCrBAWUk/r6mPducrTBj4Zp8Eju2I7DQkMICALWDRbsGUTwhhQegRGbtudp@K@0BI9WfMvLMh0pmoufJzX2l@6RGiCoWPiEjlmxFZEhVbCBXoLjNVSfGJGvbYpiRzRVkGEeIMWy7eJeLSWailpiiYHOZw0RysOGLZp0nXiAs/Qy/K0wRSSQiRLLgfDYAqEKgfF0tEUdurK8WHw9mJPClpneIgoOSlDi@puWjPFmQFFi9crX3AFO7pzR3YAK/Tk6Skni@6s9sOu4L7YoEdVwigYfHhMvjDxzDN0zmmMmFNT@BCPWwpOfGRFoD0F8PUy54bca8VwshJ5uSubBRFqVgAt3AfvMDvi0EHhxa0OswzEE1HccPMK6QxwkFqzzm@Ckx1lGVoo1pM3kjmFxDRVnW0Tp8rjpOQo4XuQ@cempXEmRo2JEDqebESnWcsaERIm84TU47At@UDBHpEqxWMj/RQWOyx2jFXshXJ7DiWJfJBEBLr/c7xKLANgv97vEggNHiv1usfDPig5YS/Gn5SJWEpwFuChR9BhoTCmqg/yAcRRqPAVFBE0a0bNizJ4yh9qIVhVjndKMqRSwSBwNF0@DHmNeMAmxkTsmjsC8elAajTC30MYZl2Y7OPFC5D7oIlXleJPAS3P6oCfMtJ8ClVFDxStJggigsfkgmOgz9/naTToxKMk7LNQHxVNRL7rx3b0xtH6rklNnDUr/dKSQ@O25xGdmT6kKu1il2ft3gtVlgmpc8OS4bYSWpTkzvtI9VKUiVMVzFymhOIsXYMo8CFPmAZiyEUyiYq9Ce0nOhIvnAJv3oTg/n8VBj3fQkRI4QNO2LRzExn7wtT65D@cSGFsJWlOn81VlQYTQTr4Px5NpHHTuejeYjROeXR1H3T6arjN96tlCzsZlZQ5FAVWJWbLSSBZpbervCjjfVKK@rXbZ6lpBTyBxf0nzcyJEZFxK3A0mgRLxU4sCZGH9zy/gXzpSrPH6wAmPDcOAtSx9ZnXQkBF8hIlvFQsiRBRZvB8qAuKMuDt0WvlRb3X6dAk8UH5hNPXenDzlAz6RQac8ZI1rrJjE@V24UDn5rZWv3@Z1z@5NPzE3/YEzABunM5cAgu/jOD4flJpS6aFpOtW1flBbNrc9m81X1G6bOvvt4ZX88UzWC5B13JgOldo2r0XrfxdmkRe/BH4HS77uy8gCIr@YSyROtOticIvZo37LdKWHVHUeQ8MH7yMtllxJSiRYzYAuszh5iG6AouORTZEkmsEoCB4bDXC@xuOLO7Fy4xiZyQV4GhZvXSdoTcYkaIy2b@q2OIpINJgXLs5fBLBpPB4dN3dRCpZtAKM9MzL8@Z7f@dE2RQiuSL6DreX5ZY9STbfCcyrSYUqCLG5rKpN4n5b7LjBwAquGoErThoovOzgZusItc2EvgWGuzh8Ce4j1dJdBBEK8KEnR4Z1CfbeMlhYzczQIWBkUzQNYOc/cCka5H2BuTR5qbv034OR0gUoRt7AeRANbulepTXfy6cJb/@Dr/pyjW96c7e/HDjxpTfxeQd90i7lcDg/BmbndDicocJbYcrJx6CyOiWcH11@6b1pZjBq/z27udXZIA4AiNE5NoJzg1MQI2pvIcVo4nmPjrpwPHofkJ/C0GS3jtILF7W/OSPgIJTLPLLH3mEHM33vm30MNhiPvMggs/noziI1m6JXsL5MD9qBHB0/UCZakETLqN4tdCzjxUaneSI/EFY80zofX8ag34TZE@YXZ6zlp9tZxe@0lme8OjUfY349GyHEQXErIK49H10OkmXll9SJXZCAI0ub0TK3nXPA7lvD@XD76SXuZXHOAM2kKtmMn5sXeeKDI9XcyCCZkOYXZTDG5gdt7LmRoomSaQr8fLT@QDMh@EHRfHygG8WkaGNpAsZcqdAFFq3iJJl8djOMpO5BlXMyhxEBUfi4M59n90MjU@eRqHxzLViDrGCzhdjna@k3FSzlZAB4wVz4f5zvIwxzHIWjCIxAfFuO2jIdO/e4fHN3GkQPc3EhjvMGW2Mh5Y9F8@IPxWLPY1bDTgerFR@Kr/lFjPjpSlZk8rVJA1oiCdc1vR2DPKMmOl@QH2OFSm9OJbcQIqRcaaZYcDTubScDwe@VR8mugqH7AT1w28VUGqvX@iO5JCfUZDcPhAopZvYMRmhhBkr4wKt9eK7VajS0PUilWqz0DRybDas9qbBc9nj1ju/D@DN8fVwrFYpmvnNtVb8Dzme95y54BDmqC8E62XXiFMLpqCbtSWMTL2cpyurzcrGxXy162XnvWyGYvwPXrP/rxr//xn2Vr4uV7fHlGL/V3AZCmadll42b58W0Z3@u7jeRyq748aCQvyihl/x8)

I am using [this interpreter](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI), command line: `1l_aoi -eu polyglot` (enable 1L_AOI_EU extension). 
In 1L_AOI_EU dialect turns are performed [a bit differently](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI/blob/b9ca944243a30f4fdf29ec8869af026fb54753de/1l_aoi.c#L209-L210).

Main code is inside and below Wierd. IP starts on second line going right, then deflects down from first `+` on the first line.
To keep 1L_AOI working columns 11 and 12 should not have pluses. I moved pluses from those columns on lines 4, 6 and 8. Plus on line 14 is compensated
with plus on line 69.

```
   +  +    
     +      line 69

   +       +

          +          + +  +    +    +
                                +++   +
 +  +  +        + +      +  +
   +             +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
  +   +                  +
       +     ++  +     +     +
          +     +
```

[image]

Cell value is increased by traversing plus going up, so simple approach would require more than 50 lines for the code. That's why I use
loop to create number 49, brainfuck equivalent `+++++++‍[<<+++++++>>-]` (blue path). TL2 is loop counter, the value is accumulated in TL0.

```
cell index  2     2   0     0  2  1 0   0 1 0 0 1
            +++++++[<<+++++++>>-]<+<+++++>+<--->+
print                             P       P     P
```

Blue path has 4 `<` instead of 2 because beginning of the first iteration of loop has different path.

[Yoob framework](http://catseye.tc/ix/yoob) can be used to debug 1L_AOI (option 1L_AOI_EU should be checked). There are some problems with pasting code in yoob, [this is workaround](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI/blob/master/copy.c) for Windows.

#### Agony

Agony is self-modifying brainfuck derivative, it loads program code into memory tape. Tape is circular and has size 1500 cells in the interpreter used, and if program has more than
1500 instructions it will overwrite itself in the tape. This answer exceeds this limit, so Agony stopped working. As [Agony specification](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Agony) does not mandate any particular tape size I consider this implementation
detail that can be altered. So Agony.java is modified in the test driver to increase tape size.

#### Refactorings

Moved Nhohnhehr into LNUSP.
Slightly modified Julia (less parens/commas): `size(...)[1]==2 ? 158+4 : 17`.
Removed old token breakers from Commercial (#70) and Cood (#91).

Answer (score 7):

## 169. [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit), 8750 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yx4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=9717 96lo
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#p>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8eAbIFiF4qOL3VVFDsmqmh4QxUokEkQWgUx0JkACxWLb7kk2t48z6W527mxuV7c9szqZ1kz3Ye0kmd3ZrpnMdF/P9kf0flyTaf7ByN0jIh94kKyZXTuBBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeEU0z6PzmNyn8sCOvO77oegM2sIMBa/nOle0b7NmYPTWdYLW0rCgYq@ZfDHu2OwjKSooVGXNcy2nBOxt4l7brfLR98C8x1ve9C9/ssUHHHDA7sMy@HTBvOOgPB8xrz062zNhez/vg5DBlz3EvINrA9vu@PaDwFcZeu12z12yZEyGrExn2fQgP2K7d/dT7NGCW1@uZbiuAmGuMvfT8wMb4lh0EHiZfZ2y0Z1sTQDcgquk73ovaqy8ngjYZ@xJQNPtde8TMZjDwTWvgeC7SpMBOXr0@OZpIUSyyN6f7@5O@JfZ1znPZ/tC6nAxaZq/9wOyak/BXWG048A4GCX@qmyPfaw0tpNugYwM4pHXb6dqBYgFNtllf1LCBDpZivm22eDSl7fkMk7DeZZc5zOr3WbNrdgyLdR2Iu1/YYDZWDfsI4d1OwEb9HgucHkAJvJ4dxz1grm23WNC3LaftWIQBs0cD2w0A08BgDpT12ul2WcvuQoIILSsLwNgwiHlxJAyl5SkMPlZ/ohDh26INcVxbEsLuQ80hITysaKCKpMe1b/b7gCRQ8gQQHzg94EtnkA6YbQYOcj4kCWy3RTTsh23CY6YbLyW7cqBmAN@hT7AD28eKMAgu69i@DSDNkCu1a98ZAAmQxDV2ZJs@O/VtW0@2j0SWkJmHOQywIAZV4dZWeu9wPw1VyVMYZn@gpPzl0x99pZjMqLLF8wp8q6paUfZe7bKbxTN08@YA1d33NVNn1e9YkD87s@E7KjbzF/6tAlAVoEqX5b3@IG/m@oBgbgAI5k10oit3VTL63VjGbGuiLmIMxmO1oDbYgcveZKlk1tD3sclHRDUvodBdz70AekJh/aGL9HDZWgGqwPKgxWaZfQVUgyZCdeRdE4VPOw5UWoBVEmsEXHARQUF0Ae8Jisp8A687pHiQMhggAwJVIClCPGizN6xtOl1MAuEIimPt28GwO8A0Q7eFNQ@CyW4ZTKJheS2M1POuIDsTgJIHtKderBUSUhAZKsKjomLQD//iz1oXFwCnZlme3xLs@oa1PItErEnIgtxiyLCea3YJLYiXxdx5csjgyuw6LXOA2btjkQUhQblee8Nui3mQoX/tQNPqmFfQHNtt2xrYnMm5VM6ynnnJZYfDORcK3jObULGUAeVNxc6xpztQS5atpIhncr3hoL3Bcv09lg7y77QnZe3JwpkNyOmGvrSYz19UgOGMJfKCt/RdnPOmlpB2wcAMPKel9MeDjueWWM5iqlX1@rarpRMw0tm030zrBso0Ta84VctoO25LS28BL25Dxmm9YlWtulNuVCaSx7MEMNcIBpurrVm6qoDIoUZxle@Zjmv0x@xNTrhiYV5wjiTHYCPmjYSZ9LviHinqlZAvPWQQkENG0LXtvlYwijqKCYw3s9wYMKukEzBEgctOI5NOpTPxohMEKGmioNhYTx0PxVa338EOCYjiBn0Q3z7yrmUC9wQoxQegGmRZk/iaRD9IFpKJ13bat1kTBKnkI2qSvMlh@hwKSgEhakLJlmy3Yg0ZhAC05UEwJY273jVkSDhh3wWiw8VMzQuoGkjMC1LjBeE5kU@ySJcuCBSE1rTZRq7pQCPA5gYyXfB8rGwQfbnE4wA03khisqdnjgGKxfvCqMEwpw1tqQfiwR8zy0aZA8LH5h0KZjKk9heAMoRqUSFXWl1NtrGpJjbw87XcT0BIf8zf2ZKw8LWEigA9T9u@Zl3TvRiaF6iPuZDEtCy7PxCCCkoSDEAUTfY35JkTnacRdJTFp5N5UyciutVYHijkee2JrtBE6SI0slwXhCkzhU7JWo4PYqk7nswdIlxNZK6@xygJBN6rc1CQGgAwmT2yreEApBow8HXHsTrAs4idy@Ui74QmsweveO4g2XPtMGtEprj9uKQY@dAL0ZgLIoc1Og0HOlcEtZ3woMqPe9wN2Qx6MwB7IYrQEcR8jbxpAO/dA7Pnud4MoEDIECxGSYbwegBN7AS1QOi4pNpFjTVUDcMqgjoDqQEtH/ivMxj0gzL0E86gM2wawCn5U398MDh0kVnyA3/sDDzubna9JojlANpnXuaQt4ZNZzRRIPIL6/BDoFyBAtYOWBV67m@HwHVauh2AwCT/HYwcC1JJcBMI/qtCRIpkAKG0dkCieB@EysnYtTTVoKZkQKNTs0zFhqvq4MBUIV12vB5KIfaWFAPU9J75ILnaIK2EzCeRb87s6kLZT3pdOm188BxXu0kvLCyky@ltkOwLC0/AtYWuJ@jKgOsJuXLkwngGuihFllwYWqcU6NdI39Yl5JHewGobYa/00elrZr1cXm5kzXpRPEv41EHUgWSD2Dl8AJy0Xq2iU9fV7WsoqNFsJ0u/g9L5xPKdviDCV@aVyd8FFZaJDE6v7/mowFawk72bJr2qD70gKK1WR/PTZ/XCWePs5qyVObtNZzG1XjGrTSgU5Kf1jAvfG0J3qddXyrliQ9fry9BJNqvpQnpJ0zZyXcjI1PUvNvSMyamtpW2Q2trZWRqIKuhTtzo@wRtlS7oekgrwwI4ZdEItbdxsQP5NvaFn0pBWT2dhiFFNp4EyFhIhoEIjZxKB9oEBd05eJIaEvUsQj8wKuqhL5HyuTsBrfol7tugRqkxldkAqpwv9JaAA3WUrHNq4nptzh6QAk3bqxTOiQRjGID/sPFAwOok4CLjtjEDDh4Y7lpoMdsCozOzAMM/r2sZb0i1UBpzPsL0aM9WZI94vGFYQVSIoLuDsd00LWmYS3JnKzgAgMGo@PztEr0wBntR1aFhyXxmhZ7BMF@nXckjtHjpBB8kLqhGOBfw2UBV1bujcbaLaAbOg074AStsjZ8CVcGCEE0zy3Aw0HdW@GlebUFvDLh@RkkN26o89CwYsNnT9GMpHf2zPvXJ8z0UiG3sAGji2gnUwAXwWeYGNarWD0u58@s4CDhSb8i7GaBuHOklcK7BY3vW63oXHliACsqZhcMY@cC1AAZS2AYwPWeB8JALVLjwYuSR50Mb@OkAlr7i2HKrPJsbMU3zjAwgLNrvQUYQ5ZT45@MkeiPjiaqEA@Mu3An3CQsagTJYRPS0WRRDNFpr@aWdoK7bV8Zh6Bh1kaZvlW/ZVHpubCj1RBzS9HGhTtk@6RJhMTFUpA28ISknL7jo9Z3BAczNdF3veqFeRoTvAXhGAI8ceKEJdjjpjnKaJBKV7wePvjVCeBopNT/bqcHfv/Kh2@ryq5oeBn@86Tai/ln3eA72pawcqYyl2bENqkeDjZffY8wZVqhKcEZr@pDCSjP9i9/zFwbPj2vE3PBtKFzi9YdfEzHj8E3qXbBKbTmr7Xi/UEQNB28VlpKadmC7EAZMIXcHQoZgsjPmvoX8PJwANS7mwLJbz@GvoKSKuY0ScFDSsfl@5yGQwJk0Shp4i5gaBxIlCw29Kz030DKcIY2p4HNys8PmJBOSbYuEWgQfuMOjHSnZTLJL/1aDdxn4k9C6R92UOwIACGXovkzefYkxkJckyFTQzcghvheDxqcmZ8KaCZkbm9X8KwvCFB4LvhRPQfHGcIZSwhz1TVKkmJLQBNQopRcN1lruaPc@gxgERbwI3XXqonUaucxhTryKUEETvsjudsg19BP0kok4hNR3C20Sv2aafGRHKYggLDRwnUpEqX@E0HI6yPeix7WuKRso4AQNqOa6ZP6YHquWz8EkOMBLINO32EDqzPGhL6L4nWm5zg2K2m01nXlSgC6IunzOi@cPmLLLB4KAzNQZlCcIPhv6ga7fE87/8XgsqYLp6OuaYOvDQcQ50I95oz60tkRRf6Gd2zVKcD8OuYxIZyHUfSMvEaT@zGzpmg0ZZzHK5jun3sJ8UlQvMiT/Q1u/gM465b3eHLVs@Z2dCJE6OdHlq1@lRieCJih4p7nOST4zTeXpSlbqe2SIoXKFx7Ki2eb3YI961x5QAEKcPwFMOp1k0fw3jxsGQ/@KU9X316vTxO5sq5SSTFVbNZtHOe4HZdOw7@MA3L4ctL9e/vKBCI2pr87idNyIc/eXaXfOSO8/ROZsAvIi@c3EBo17xnBftugMKS9AHlSd/TY87WEV2KIx6ffMumH6X/86LIlf3Qsd8Ojld@vkchiQWsaDVIGlxMSkXI5MzQdiu2RzjuK3z@ZyFGVJPDYKnamUyhWXsxsJJyGjZqt@fnx77Pkq/uTk7NV/hIgCW127b9n2tGXokp2d2c6VWzDlXOMtZhcg1Iypp0jmrawbAJANBZvsKqoV@7mJc7GQsZJfIdQfbRujIOeZ505VRmr5jeV0n6POWJF7mScnJiZ4IDK5j0k@UFN@m6duC4QJ24LnQNbuhe9YApwzn8NEDBBefrcP50BhjGN482lneNX7nqg4d78rmv7M7s48zsXqACMp1iTMca0bylnUfu@KiE/3MpuLlTKwGVnemf5m99Dy/Y7sBKxkFOb2BM/5mt8unD08PDufzdOB0vQBGGvh7Fy1gRBEE/Hc2N8fJ5phujiZx4u7ZyQRSfWaIMe@cyjS7F153beMib8LP3Bof@m2U7OL5UIkWSqRi8V6JFCo@nlsUz7mi/BL@72MGmijycUY45ryjH50lvsRM4vwCwvAAl3lmF26/sEEpjTwf9s2rAN/qXJtj@fwteot51JW9RX9MajPodZhgcwMcA5@r0r9Nbit359Z6mEyaArt@XyFilXvZtUFC0@9UlbJSofiZKYqFwsMlVLs7tIf2TIlx2Pxgo3XNHbLi4UgVRDEWxRRIHoiHEyBhrI9iUPggrLH/xrc7BYzZdaCR36u9zJR3fdC1@ziOPgLHETqmE164w36icmO0Ox66x3dTrtOXLdtrJZDEkM@VSBv360gJdTyw6TtPdd/reTD09XqgM7gPqH8BlOaU@G8CMPlEkD84OP/m3wm3zMKlI9BXQf@AWnUugxxO4j1M8JTmjdkp8uYmjMpcezDG33nUniVIm57X/ZzaAXnaclAtA2UTbcPuq6UpXUesIrJodiLAmY5me968BO9rxAASqIeD5bkVfQRFGlDn8JBanpo0vKPXik0h3jeOhB6bJn8C35LuefgeY@MuGhvG@p0Ic3XUa9pdkz9Gayt3wds0lh@iEvWlnkuzyDjzzOeao5WP1IQI6o@BWE4rF1gdu2fT6x1Kvtn6MAzkY26kkYffGcFGnqZZ56TrO9DmXfxNzGvHtKKB59pBfmD6FzYOT7q43CB858lZOXs7k7gHPfPC3r@XuaLZBzQxoeW8mHP2PESZr/pakOweScJHfp57aY8D@ZytH48tqM9h705os9q5hZOc9zZsIz9z0voetc/teB23Y3d8ahzh27zmARw54Ka1dxUC8O@YwSXa1JBMioZ1nSBO3a7X7T6EuigTuYT0vNnzr3toxNqCpJ8Fd2w2IUA87p2qg66biER9@Ly207GH0EMF3sDr2zl6mxe1i5M6/Hf2lPLBYTpgbx3bb/H1RJzhMwdOs2uzawdQ@BDE1@VmTxg1u56JZlt3KPFAGfl8yBSU5fn39QoXpjfo9@lx3u8OA/qhmdxce/YUZZntE6IP4QVnwFdyOcfaF17T6jj3VV7TNgeuc5kXrV@8zubypCymgjsst4veRtcBUvljA3mgGg8/wcfB7HbvvBCG8XfqIztD3x/fLxuSq5ThrCpfC0DHvPkXsfo0I5h6fjRXkMvydyxIiMWquQxFujTqzTm7AMpJce5sUMK0QpCgu7w8uIdKlmdd3qtOzJ2fFAubSCrLiS2/gv/kJMbdaDwX4g0Gh9rz4UWg3xd/jKrWrtPjpvZmNzIquidl7YJzDi4kBV3vOjbRDCLBdMVjJueVXtzfnmg1ZPXOhZEyK744rx0e3A/M6jr9gP@yXLs0U4WYXrycleM3WIV3U@YEWkL74YOHnuejHSpoGznLtwMLJ8FRUHMBysWT612AwM51WRRZxp1ZlumF06lYfNX0mOznQ0vLICsM/8HP8YWZdxDupUiRLQbZXUo7PJZCa9Ahsu/A8w1G8TTNzGR0XeGJcCLwwoVoMhZZs6OlKzeUD1jXCQYU12mzep0t3ozKhXLxllWZWlZZo8Ghks3l3qhPZujHPGl90WxUF9O5XHoxfeaWWSFNUe1uYM@OaibitR16cDyjojPX5JY26JYlrXAL3qBD1vEg6lvQZbyGgQaJDc/ndqjcyPkUVxT/81@2xKYBUCsD1nOAv4AQuNHF69kd7/oJz1fkXuv3Tdx0gDCuO9gfYe65nRoLrrFv4XsFvGv2ev90Q1ggi@048HKEQjCGBa9UHOOg@dGAVxrHpuXZnDdFxmEqWSjL6w57LnTmrUEnMICfybJo6EcWFeDCaO7AR42mlWUHrGXjug0ZjJES3/W8SzLdREz@819yu2syGxPmPDJ72m8RyxGtw4pk7GxZ3hCwlkA@2r4nomhIZODsIQ6RoWXZ3F9HYyoyCAdOzElzaMyGm0Tv1E5Ybo@lcb8QGllWnLa2WDv@8k290Kh@x3p5@7/8Xl6/EXRTv8htrgVqlskolVvkq3jwKgRHoWmmLo5UUSzcmUIbMUKmElvZNHRTdUnz5h5taiG@s6/JvJmMclxsuLhbBERzAGrkQCfQvNFUF7UhH4zlTgZsFTdVwfjGBBffBkPGYmiqi0kWR@wT6yCv5Cw0YII3TpAuWof3qs/kevxy3Goiv2s3h7RUeFUySstVKs7ieXVrm1y@3fJwl0b93dmoVMidjdb3GvlAEufsbPRFofRjoJ4HeuLi4zw2oL1XuzeLxnbh06fAHDNVvU1XuDEItPLFm6ODo72T09rp6xOg5i0vbGrf83tmJCmQF8geq@N1afsLkMV37OB@6RFKkPANomsaWzTZFu7A03UlboxEUQWp1Zy6yJ1hFBgwxVPfk3xW@sCOhU9HEJKp7TAhRdkRMZLgmXQQl6BZyVtYL9jcQa0NKYKmNjNEIdFIZVWgUg6o9EAaselS8hp8Qh5QjfcT6m4Ys0AAraIY0xGQSGFeWF4ezgs3s/C3/wAl7kO/9ruWmGDcWWKMcVeJIWKUjFLs1w5evD7eSyYCdor2OsKg1MftsG1qW3zXFOcuT2zQkZKJxnOBMMgPZWvArpyAxnvIb23sGbogXLA5ksVAgNKFm@@yWjcASd5qgWhqjgco2UCkG2QDxg3Bci5TU0AsI@xos0xVMG5Qnd6wAZLr2gIp9p4nXqR4BDlQZuwsO7PzP/yLP@O7yc4G4P5D4R4VnsHbH4u3Nrj/uQwpFuHtX4ZvJXj7GX97l0dSTm@h4aUJiYgEfHNwxAIakiKJeuYoVnrs27DvdFwYFDk9oPUVkQ6j82JFlIngaPU3QHmoLiA7CmmUy5Sf7Tc03ABRzudRFcF5RIPslOwRH5DSfohvh7gPELqS/Nrq2koRRmR27koCJJvmCzSM4QB1vQxcqVw5/er7psW2traYGlhm166uVTjJ84vmu2X1fYjoIsRVuNZSZ5AGkkQpIGxbJNMWzUxRx6TYONPFNGtUQCHhNQh9mkYOiKKjtyvNYqHT9ASpgD1cezQgwT@W2hioQi5ZZdp8N6gElANAHDbuVpvk8sjUBS0DY3xvxKtBfYvRTjBaWZ3FZPV37Gxw5jbErkUGDPPLGSzngvuPZmxlDLmnNr2HTpvcAYelYU9PXA9NovYBW6aV8qXlfHFNj7UpVYACfLEFfQKQ0GagDVq288HrB7WdvYOvDo9OpvaCUcz0ZLQ0S29vZc5yRrbeCB3pCa6XRH22nz95@WxfkjKOVbSigDGiZYVJNGflNonpnNzfchuj6bwpYCqjYuGhgGlYnNunlbdp6FFoPhZxh9tATOWq6Te39cbW9pmbmsr@06z9sSljCZkLXGcB7Y5Nsxky50BaTp3iAQmBIQ1tS2q0@zs0reXvkff83VzhcQvRli5po6WQtXporK4Yc6y3oOxGnmdF@5k4YhJfkDUS1SKiGmVoKVOrQnFsmCjL9MkQwso4JNIhH8jSNlXThTGM71g8dkACmg93aW8lDHgOBtEYCcZdOBVCQ8ExDXtAVISTMS2HRtemL22qw5ATu@fkTiU@KDiiLVpib1IHytZ1mhWzWh@x0ED5rp1KRtDvOgMNt02NDBxOQmk0HQtQ3MJ9RyN9a7MhtngxuRMrQ5u5joZAryOvz6Ih/K4tXccwimO7QwAObGCzr4Y9iNemx7GNvYTNXnk5SAx0TEsk6rh9SZTB6LVWIXejY49azgX0NJqeBZH0RbEYbQMzcR@TmwY5zEn1JZrKxAnzWVvXYhQz66bhuC17pOGOi3IDqQP@6eu3V2ldneIB2j8ntpO1JjfSSWFhDkSrjTahTQiEzc1QECTbzuam0QkUNCCHEQjkeDLwX4AT@lCt3TP7TBvSTsSAGYxetTPNzQYDX2e5bezPrpnLMhkau8CDAgxGKdvkcro4H63hxn0tX4V6Rt/AbeHjo9Nn9aJhNMBNmehsEWcfdkDdwHG7roBqCknKBBY6YPgrI0bXMEpDjPhzkbJVaC8RxJoZTA35okMNEGhBpWbbj6OtK7EWyKm6uVkWtZEUh5sM2GJrhsQAsDPEnNRNgb7CBBiohkIMYu3AoNQBgfL0a9t1ob1qwDM9aJ3MHAKT@XpWnkyTjQ4koBxSHMXnwqYYEE0eVLCXvul6oM8s5is0Aq7cQr///gw7/rbo@sf5/zZv5Cs32mK3Os6DMqZva4udajGzvJTJLLpL2qKL6sjjxzhwvl0EbefcUA11BJFyi129AvwM2lF10a0smlvaYqtaWqIU8JrJ6DeQ4Lsgb9wsmrf5xcegTWTBx@etU1sMaA9hwTCKt4AftpDFfBZ45gb30tF5M5j9opPJIA7G4jki8F3@7CRD/crZSZ7G6BWh5OYvelKMJHWVsCamzsnhBBTe5VCir6JEF@vG5zJy/JiCGWF3atdfo5UNoxUBOwji/JUMebhgEQINhZMQMhrfxAkEHGlARHzNmroOwuQ3v0kV12DU92RtWfMyT1YLlUx6tVhJp1jqqZpfUn315mw3d8XsXLreNleNbxtHl0dHP9bPNLbJ0qmdQ7W4or5jm6WlvJLKLxU@refz79@/B3WY1beNbaOh13PpRl3jA7p1tr2@vpRd21jKPk2fRyPIdaZrpZIOlXbGVtnZumkuZVZKT90KhGziZ5kVwYm/G/AtstVVtoefv/0//vYXf/tz@vsFff/acZx@0GrB1@uwS/YRPpdthv/k/tiKuU10N9sfNRhngPpZpaZRPEqnV5fTJ@9wt/CTBfijf/iEr/i7QD7Cm6JMfxaU1LaV@pgqFoupMf2do7s4ig2ec/QymvfJF4ulMzwNYXlt4SkDqtogRPFTLj8NYeTV9Q3V88ijAzmsMi/FWoexXEY5/Cgped5Grm62G2xQwz922sS/4wH@5d5c4t@xhX/PLvHvZRP/jk7wrx/g34869Ofj33MX/5rf4t@Lj/h3auEfYb9RzTJA/rtqlSPNBPKTn9nehnEuXQjl/db76u/2YZ/z6SspGPSltrcbmdztbd14l6lUxD@Iy0r4hh/uAnwbt7nc1rvtTKZOeNe3RQG2co1tXhr6Nc7fbQHYzFZ9a8s4394ebeca77brWMob/LGCW3yUVGiCZ0vorI62jjnIXQkT2wXDP/q84LnUj17AKOc0W9rKpUr7tZ1s6eT1s1QR3lajVwxcxtfjvdru4WuIffRir3ay9@XBm73XR@AfNM63nz7NGMAzTwHh7UZdSY2@yGxnqoPB4Pwn50sGdpCbvJ/cDHGY@JzPcPFXJbW7PXqdz20B0i/ON7GAx5RbDqjR@MQ4WCVVT9W1zJPMk0K3cFUoXhYvX3qH0f/h4QgCnFHhg@cXOoVOsQVtixXs14VxYTwq9LzDYgucNvwVeuB0Cu1R4aLgFtxicTxaOVw7fJqAN/@/d@gNXh56ANKD5INRYYDQC214XhwevgSgbUDgA/w5hUJhBJiOClfwX@gW6fPuvADF1nFnLbwVCmdnSp2p722QlEYxbRTSxlo67TRW1/rf3tyW1r6tk2K3utmo4ybqhsqy6fOzerpRSeWDs7M8F@pqaUWt0C7r29vz893aae38PI/zYaOtxczTTO4pfKrbmS3xeJJqbVeenJVzyIGSF1P5rSdn28s5dK9lgP4l8NvKZz7zE4GE5/bCmZLWrt@@fYvft9dX19xFDu539jYMxZ@3efDiLvSCD0bNz0qfdIymmU7T6quNm1vo3M7SlbTo/jRGJxaoxbNRqc1KKg4xtE0dNIziMuqxa6tM395eWwWPtQ09pxVwCMKTnKn9fv9MNWjSxSDb0mq15vvmGAda2goA0TZXq9Uz1fTPz9R6qYFpV3Oba8zzc5vLuqrr74pbW5AHZlHSwVtNj1TPT7Ob2/ifdnO7pdFHxz9dR08d2Iae27oGEfRVeBvdaGxL29LQD7ww3c3tNjop3g246pre0G9vuR/8avoWh7qtA@EYaBf/SP/Q6/z/5//laxaAknKbQrXZZSurutYc2/rKmraR2RR/1QUgrKYup5dRH0qb6Xr96dLy0vpK/UljyVjCr7Z1tt2Y0TfroCVBS5Ztr1pMYcWiMDMqx2qxpKbRnUpVLHFGQ9e7YMubFezOMaEKH3QpaQYVur0VsnDUbevbWP@MapTpDabf3gBb80BQrTWxOnV2NioUZCKdVZrVxZuUeVtJYS7sVpVJRAuhPLR0hZYw1Rt10fTrxYZ6qy7eNG9xHLJU1EkFXV2pVJZWuHtR04qba6XNUml9bW2juL4BmslaoZBnxeJGaWVjeXVzZWVtY3UNxJuuVyjDpeKSgFMAOMK5UanYgWlVUHBVUoCHpsGID4ifOlOqTfsCsgcC9eNtOrO6urqQL8Fj9MXaXmm0sLVEn@2lmZ@N0kZmKfO0vrS5iZXYIM9PC0oFVxT58qWaU7loYBubhEkK1z74osPiEegj4m9pd4m7ivjdWwiUPnNhRLteYC2vizsEvXZ7ATw7ZsCatg1DN7vblYeAwOiy27p2WvaCUu@N2g3ahV3N1Ytrq40cMMaHUZsRMyiBDZ/ekWkPbft6OLy2w8@OE5gfPph9@ozaP/zypz/88r//4Vc/@@FXP/3hV7/49fe/@Cl8/xK@P@PPn/37zVX8/fX3//J/@eHPfwWefw3f/wTf//jr7//N7/Evvf8NfP@vmN/fiG8sHv8qAOuPf/39z//i19//8z@F778V3z@d/P7wr/8D//@/xR86f/XDv/4b/BEvP/0ZFPfv/@qX@P/zv/r7//RL/P9f/@e//6t/9fd//O/I8Wfc8f/823/Pf//u93/6d//0T/7u97@f8/vTO3@/f4D/9/8IPg/H8yFwHlKuz/X5/rfC53ehRpQL8ABw2h/98G/@AHj1X/O3fwZv8B8G/WH4kgjhL38YvQCE/2lGoj/69fd/8hfh2x8kIybCAMgfQtifJ8L@8Idf/t4Pf/Hf/fDLP/vhl3@MrTS3spmtZXPFu0cNKYi4@oB4GHHtIfEgIo@ywBaUEj3xR3iyBXKNlpTVZRxc5fgnwz0/LaK@yc4@KavwnvmUx9NdWP6TCD3DrTxFCF1eodACKM8FDF3FVxkaQwVXq588Tej0HJGlT08ZRIbEscgU8QlHVPhnPiXEOqak8IUQcfhGmS2E6RdmEOYJewrB0GtSx7mFv/gCPs9gpCcGfNXtDVZVsmyjyrbZM4xYhXcKRye9Qx@LBx1XlV32DIeo6L0LFOLjcjZS3uPAO0PRt3lUtq1A@Hfg8YyDIWgI6jsFvDLcZxee34n4I4Xg4b/QWtGNXxkAPxnG/eAVex2CI34UHoMHM/mIUxOH1xgP043wn0WABJyMAoTIZOMDsjCLTOSlhK@ZqVxCfCbCMlEYE51nAlSGTQG8KzDhrUwmZDOhCAzmhk4UU4bOyFGGpqaThEFxAmUySYJhymShMkoG7eKWRKZLmSUyg1n63I/AiTKYSY47PnF6L0Ulj8ONsI@gEr48QYbiRnkTRI3rVLSOwIprKyFgXdHoDDDQSHFOw@6DUqe8DC6eeSOtkFXVbHFt9sSBjjMgEPcbr1yufldcWVfgSe9DPI5MHIwFvI1nTBtb8AE8lO2bHAoBZftk7xTCTg9ZsVQwWL3QuFlZL62srqyWltfWVtdLxZW1zZW11Y3lQrGwVlgtlYqgum5ubK7fKts/ZiODHR39KHcLgEa5XL6EEFm1uLpeGVchJXkp26TJcQ1yfJMD5RExOCP19QatFnD@5obm9h7BhymPFPYIvOCTu1Vw8paJRbODw4pYWkEDu1BH5@ssanF1UyWVPpcLlDPbbXHgSj/2UU7xeNFXAAzI4bIXaG838Nip59Ghas9sa06MnQ4/IHzH94Lgd4jzzHQvedCug2ebWIMw6LmJO5yDnjPozInxut9Dk2Lb/0eDsNdrAoI47ckjPIMfv@t5syKss9dHc0r5MrRUxlUZMlWG6McHXz4/jT1P92o7z5U19uzw1e7EY1VEWmUv9vZPw9d1HiqTroYgvtl78WLyVTxwILPAVtezWcMw4AefWfrQ01h8J6MUjfmKhbpWKK2rxez52IbRzE0ud3vhNO3iGgxdV9THKRhE4eF0J/z4vYHbYqM2sf3menGdba51PeUlGqhsFrllsROgCSVAunbJgrWJB/sO@/M94YFe6PSdiw6Ij2svjBAEwfV1OGH0Vs4OhbNEb1nTNPH7uR/IwY5/Bnd7DHge5DcV0p2OrjyH4WEPD7DDvUQDXBZx2qygGCgqSqXNjdWNzeXSRnZjc2NlFQaCq9liKQuj6fXNQrZYKG4UYQy9WcxurGwur4BUgtDVzXUlBU3faefzIHuLqkpPx7XwJKMtPBLKMzrbSqplt5FX2Uhr6SzVCj2GG0xd3jgrMEioKmj1tjSqqqUVtAdcLrKiqqgms1hqf3@nsL@vqs/wBecqdwqq2sKX1Y1CYf2ZqtoUsgOSswSJOvi2t4aTmqrq4MtObX8fIXzAl9IGwlDVSx7CX7ryZR2iufiyvIwAmKp@G4IrAHCPY7RBqQb8pVB4tqOqQ47eBvxBvBp/WyFk9/AFAzDRPg/ZgTBV/VImAgVYVY95PJHVc1neWk1VD/hLrYYgvqLCr/JCfY0vNfpAIh/egHNV9QIcFz4M/VW1CU7kX1W1wGWNTfDrgQt3T7oDU1XHvBxYElUdUWzTulTVc@kP@QA@z5@bnUHLvuCfsc@fFgQdQJAzGu7tN7/8snlx0fTHtb0vjynoq6@emx/GQ7950RQJm@fw8TAVBF32xpMfG4POz83u7KCvIcidCDofn9uE4bn5LWAmPheYUe/8Kwz6CoJmLWQJgPDpQeQmfp714PnMbPIg@aEgeo6aTbWCLItNp60R45pZetB5ifoNQ3uEQDOfkMgqo7jy2qBbDDf03OqT4Ya6tq6Wl@CpPlGXwQlNgxXSBcbU9Jmq6vXNxhN1fVUtp588yaUfF58wdX1TLavr69Dp6pVblHaaftPWRtlRtQAe@fwWNmhsgvAM1QDRV5c2VJCh4C0j8JYftl3oxEFcM/jmcgqG96sCY5VpeGwrrjrRIrWWTq@X0mk9XYG0CyrgIlChhSksssRYBZkBGG@WILlvD4bQYRUqt1M5@5flYGD6aKVAOZSZugaaBXjjWbjTn6cwMM2Wl5qrW9v/ZOrz3/yTWZ/ZvvhRuJ60VlRSt0oLTy5a2VRSN8rtze3WtszxazYemxk5@GOPGbvILCqLaSx4ejk52qlVaxfHNTmnWduBMfeyt@KlFhcXldTW6ba6rB4a5@Eyxnae1sbOcOEMF5mMs/OthcxvtcaRM7afynVBQD2v@Daa7LfwihG@1LCxihVxwYJU5rf8QCZKFWAqFZwfVlPYeqyuN8RF3q0zXqCt71K0FMGObtpDl2y2yi9RjdTMMu@w6w1g4e9eOd2bjeXcNpkaaMBht7fEFdYhrQMrKdcTTiAkaPADezTQQOtcVYUabrP@yea79Xcb716@Pnx9uM@eFsobZRjSngGPZIvpYhqq8Cl0Us7xHowLPnmrxe/cryqpcj@9vJJeDqvsrJri9AE3Mr1WrxcbrL7caNSB0RpMh9dqtfSkuLqRWSmDfqGntnFPRWk91QdSo7O4XsgtpxoCzsq6Dm6aUi4VU2@Tn@vEyxWtmCqpjZfvcf5B3obhlMiVzzO2eLt1C//bt6y@tXWLAwr8vRVPCOPh9I@lkS/0iD6JeFGcKPy3YzrjPNX4LrfF/7fwZ@eQE0FdW1X11PvqNrDCu/N35ykltcnUEtVeJi/GB4xx1WTJpT87eLcUwF/ksQS61lL4Zm8tBWx1uwiDPnspn8@f6T8qgd6yubm2sZZSfgPkusNCE0JDk6W2DXr7sDfLZqnmOy9NtOdyQ7slcLwcfsRjj5/KC0@kisNQx0GjPFRy4n5C74l50T1BSb9xkMcdJOirKOhy6JIr1iY2xKWZAe0EYEu4Zxo3yunKjfIIYA2tAW0@gZ@KojzCXRD4qsl4WfY4GOg4k1TQlUePhPgNBkYwOEfgmEh45ooV5VZB8pitVsDo4HFcUeS760zcU@D1@eEi3THjiQJqKFxfo41xmG8M4SXW5lhAaZYY5UiYY@F49o94tOawjajsH7zYgzQw0myT9ZBIrfpNPJafirfQ1lnYiwAN8GzqqqAURceIAA48eXes93ALn6VRzAwrYnibrJAgVpYVs4RJlrVFwjq@NiA5gm@DVAsAMM9d4yVgS@ciW1EGgQ8VAkiIpaPOEB2mf2FlRe3hwZv1hs5u5EYhDUPZFitFO5kELKgMfpUWJbR6LXHEeDUiM0ErNrJQtRW@4UQL4wmfiFC3ytIg26vwqupXlK81C7QGz9cq3/UeP7be9eu9RkXvVQf4zGR60EFfag6PsjSo9qrAHv2606gM6pmM06j29K81fMeT/LE3F7pPoIuyQcndKuCCVl2Bnv1Yd3PfuY3sft3NAMrD7NJPqh@zZrWAWkvWqRaz3ey31aIoB@Q5qH7MuBVzC75oiZfYzAM6ScasJLwwyaXWrX6smw1Ug7qQMJPZh8IAnkG9m8k0dMi8C4HTCSvdx4/NTHd7VOnmcjrGerf8ZL8@AEcjU8X3smZujZ58rA8hfVmDZxWy6eqAPKQTtL4NcQf8KkBjXqcR6hxH0tJGgF6vWl36yZOlnyxVFxY@1ke5XiPLyV8uRNyAyI8Q@Upss5S29BOdTZCEFlk19Qun/IUBwlHNOpkMEDnbj6XkGC79BEL6mYzE@hblJV3wI608kcPEBh9@qjcd6UtG23S0ekA3FAxauNUR0tYCy3FEdL5Hte/AeNnEffNZOr7fpBgYJm4cw8Cz0ZMnisxa7CmBnFG4NG1m4rib7p3xcbWXbq/jRwTcJ19niWEpc8PxJh0lDyPb5bVYcyXRRA0u8K06RkExcFO4rXCJxXcSgbAh6QFxSHpgvBxKESSSkBMiZlUEQm3JCoJUKCfa/HgL2siP8gk167DlgwjhaEBjnoGGk/1QJdkE/OSAizlblB84oKkoj6AQiAOWwWmwbRBk7PFjJl63qqxYWse@AKNhvA@ZIkaawhQyfwCmAAOx/AA8ivKQMgHcHmEI7pRLZLTyu2UkNrpqkCDzIcv3uxq031UbugHf5o100zkaWBePHn3IVFcEQvBPAxNID2G3v0mJ7r7Mdg5fHr0@3Tt@WTuBXxiobcRv6JC3X03dfdPHO22ajku7vSzzuGh/85XFmAZq7wDP58XL7Vrsq9cvWKn0ajeLp@sB6VN8chg61HIIyQ7o9PLA8PyL/LVz6eSTV2ziPWS0sYwu9MzJqzwQHeqcu9Hm82jveYCTXtCZiyPBErdm9OwgEFf65OT1iHQgC23D7@FucmiF4gogstmXZsdk5I4WBlnaOuE7Fw7dedfhABLp6TKEAU9O7UPBq3ta5sBEjlY2NwqFMitk0VGUjpJ0LEvHinSsSseadKxLx4Z0bApHUUIucsgw9F1eXouc65FzI3Juhs6VQuSMIKyUIudy5FyJnKuRM8ptJcxtbYPgspSkJjVd28ew4sqGDMMTLGDsg56rAKY46bkCiJamYkLylSlPyG8j6bm@WRAZHeQPMVKptBa9g/SRcasaxyrL8cjynPmb8IS@SuHDPGLYPd8HqbQ3wrvKgOn0MsPNtIqCp3NYXdsEZcAegJZS3Qf@t/UyP2TCH5ejDbUIoVoM3yE5XpUBaYp03R5nnxnBpVnBHFppJjR@VAgLCRPbjSyQ5FiWEz0th7iS8ItDXUABixSdE6PEY2AdJLcvyzxP/eHMLJfvzjIBcGaWU0hxuKuzUiFtNAJelUmp/ydoVZkf11Nsqm1QA8TlqsQDExWKp41Ub4pl9dff/@n/xn79/c9/xX7481/9v//xf0T3f8Cf/x10FlYKI/zs54xsIeDnXzGyfCArjCgRxV8uqz/86S/h9X/4d@yHn/6cB/3JX6jZlRAQhKBXlPIX/wx//gB//k81uxpG/MUf8YiYRM3eKgnVSoNYP/trxiA3hBIC@9O/ZEzNgIKhCc6r8zbeiJ1NwAGEZKiTqzEZzn/xiiqgcUHPqABXvBWjtwxWgB4D7pt4W2jU9kCd4Yt2KKUt0@rg/nPh5QWo/1iowniBcQH8dt0CpUfMVqSh9L/PyiydwTg4sYKHrFS5DBflF@VWo1CMm1HzgB1ecyNA0QVeISYwvFWAv2kkMA4MHLbQiLTIeUTQ9xXeRiw7EFVyFt1npIi8ZGqclhF3O9IFV3Koi0yL3RA/pITudVLEBuliLMOEuJmoNshl0geGjNGxBfGk5GH3@lAlkCykNxIWX4gK2UlwUc2JZrN3uD/RYPDTBBXzMi6RwoyqTFXviYuUFvF11LiWk/E5viJCvVBebiQOQZgVWf3xj3@sKjG/AvKQ39IIQqxQXGSEQcVkUCkWVIoFAc4cJsma1VJpAgfqOFAuJg/84MliIiqZLGIubDmyHhANGAvyCdFsuzsMOtVp0CSRk8JuGngMZLFRFe3kzCWZs81UfSoBwEymqU7W5WzQhak40xU1OyVSO@GTqK35kBJpYo2CqKdMUimsueLmrJpLZngH6GIj88CMSoXfMaPcAzNaW70/o8lqxbQJ8PPpe7/YkWIilPARMN7wU4kOCrvGPwXWi8QRYuyTU9NhyFMTQ57mtce0GZd4gn9eHqebuLnTjx2yi4OYV97A5tMDT/seDDk81IJjFwW/FtETww5@w/aF6/l2ED/cxOHbv900Hq9jeRcu9GpZPNbXEdfS4io8P80t2a@EPZvQQnf4LeIImhMKNc/zc8d1BufnoHx223pEQHw1LNyTm1bw@nFwxdJroWp72Nc8PJ58oN8Pk/RdnuzUsS61w74ITEMmNQYDOsvuwuCLdfCCwsDjJMEi8isLQSNtDjQ6Q7Dj9bwL2/XwZCFMPQH@IIKNCJn9PuGSZWaWWTGMxCBas7KmLpJ@/dlJ2dclvGJTpi8lASSIkWX@JI2Rsv6M7M7nZseTyfxOPh/fkzi@J3fj23b8YDCJM3nibA8@Py/rZS2CABEjNJbvRyMrDhObQieBSuiNl@PyBA9GsUWWQS3EtAZRayK60Qb@yIZvAe2@FYi/mUf/uytQJt97aPWRMnsyBnnTo7ssaYgW0HmOrmVrEP1A1yPbvlh2IWvvPjAvMdChEV6WqSS4XNzaDQ2z37ddvE6RfyTge3gezYOm@J5shqo8cAZO/lWWXZbmV9HuecvummO7pYmY2RhcWeJj22yRvHpYwVHQkdDz@I3IWiFbTKhidAQHRSrPYRkze6Xr89mKR3FC7qHFOMLwYD79aOJuUjTjJGiVr4F4PkjQFJ3SR2cj9sf9MT@2p0vnaUk5yvsfXpOv8DSjewkCdOA3hhazUbb6XeLzWAuL9IAeIYxrJItMm99lt@WBNj5Vh59HovtLSrMMYaKqrOWEdjKvxp27ajzGFZInuVbyMJa8j@kezHMxVuPAIhG283ldyBTkHbPbtSwtDpH73FljnjslE9APa8xz5/Qq5zMEapiSJN0Ar1Orcv1CVxxwHsDzCp5v4IkAYQx6zhlKlg31WjnlRSE9sx/TWoRP3UJdNEZFPb6OGIulSDdO5N6GeVpz87Sm8rQSeYYtIJllLJJiJbIUtYDVc1cVdO32YI50xiAcucPjLrENH9czfVx7vUk76bKTZemrdBkEctpOl/c0EMrpVrq8S44gXT4hx2W6/DU4oraV/pQuy2aBEXx4JcdT9BciHN@tdHlH02@VAR5RKvM10uWwTiHOE/5KFLnl06tNservhbOqNl53jUplliHHBPDwsFj1Rpa@BfinqOLoWwhcqLLSEkXGAUii04j1GDwf6DYMvLDc12Z1H2U5NSXmN6I5FAjPVGOTKsglQ5JH6VQ6KYw4YhhKk4/wBARRbpZnY8SKUyOz@9ARuTt40TgQO5k/Uc8gfaClUXgdIscncbpRellfSRC8Ah@GJyaeh@cUOjI7wgiNAfQZaCFR36fvKBTW9cQxqrz24zU0PUeAlZiTUXgtEdiYTAcdDnVTyqzv9ZNMQqG42ufE0@BHNErk3olkJBVEy5wTTN6iZCgY4o1fv6s4sXSIWkIEYWC90OCtLOwXSBZjUCTrYpoqb3yAQkzmtOhcMxvZdlc4KR4XN1nqK@Z1QzItz5IkV1JMQmIDTwMYmgOee7Qug2cEfN7wVaYEFRxwRACxlGEuXL56n6G/e1x/lwq1JMJEBrMU69ld6bR6fWcvO4F5N8p2ugIxMMt29ZnKUZhDRHIYHcQ087t4bUrFx5t3uZLPMw2hT2j7kmzhmOAeuk2OLTgs1BL8q6TnJU7MXpbmE2paI@leGVJpMTAnAYcXPMQ0KtrduPKCz6piDME@Gh6fXcF@soLjlYfwqAD@BMl5K/eHLplXRW2bTqeKVi74qoOHVmLhocAxTxD3ZL8WmmiBx@H58e7hqxffQKe7vr6uTy9FYKuFtFE/rty5TBAOW0pZPNcRj6Im24mO5w8Wzlx12qSMPEAZMGndhrOfaOO6kGUxeT7RdiEdjxujqIB1GTUDMyGVUNUxsct2BF35dU/akimASPUW6J2l0RquGiF34ILO@Tl1X@fnaJxzfi56MayacBnpNylx8XMpstdQUklrJtK4gqnD03ACYNijbUNyAk4ci8btUFIA52AgU4ephu7AkcYOOD9EuwflWr62XMTZiYN26EN4oFGGVlrBIWxpFQ9X4akwNk58kmmlyGeBKzp4O0DQ91w635nOzCS1He8qCOTUK6E9dK9NMgPhudCZMDGMuEGWXBfzXH5wf8DT4jZFmkKWtMky@8KgFZ/SJgw5Lp0@P/Y3NP0IdEpECJONFtC42bV7gNIJ8O6M2eSXDtRKZ9@5uABGyos7zLiBy6kJSXNeO7cjj7NLsTdm12nJg9WFTRhdaiDmgYGcWuI8woCV1kCb2swCZaMvEBbNZBieOVggIy2KBd91eKxz50Y2lnZBG@vJZ1F@dIS3oJ1jzfK94Y6P95VdmW6MzvT5FJ@aFouWJAdiK5fyBDxFHIVapXVKA23U@pqaUuXReOjkZhNm15In9Wl4RmRZeeSS4EELMGZx2xpQcF1U2mh5TQ9NUl32BVsuKXSdg0eTyzxbgMFX9hLQIQySIrLcuk8IGPWLlvoFLiYqj1IoCzmvYXrJyuimI9YjXmYLAhxfUMGmzJuAfFmNvSzDUOPRjIwXNDUDUDKqriYgQXyx@vGIS97ppCAUQTx8rim27fsuRVOuQJQwunxWmBFX7jDsJcteNB9M2PXiYCpuqNkW9mv8xqas@hotsMo8E@o7DDz5FEV3ZVJ254rSXJMeaCfNlmhLbjvR0ag@Jg7RWHDcuxCgHoU4FOUMmX99EZThCzhkJUggE1ksaEQb/V7ciCJoR40nORQalViXohXj2CCC7QAEShvomVW/QKvVx5CQuljo7/RZalOhkkgPyAV9lyy51ZyhUlJhdYyQkiB4baJ/aPuqkMG7FFx3nOVu5osbhbVNsp9mbnaQ7dU3G9klq6oye@CYbi8Y@tetywuvcwXKAut/aI6s8cdvGVtdYbjFpPSY71YvrlXztCF9nU502KQjkRblcRF05sGZyhhticXTKdKMhRuOKgu4TR0@Wfwpq5UpLmVLPcmF3Ii6V19rVN1qodKru42Km8nog0x1kClmNPR4XNQrIGn5tEt90CCryPwSeylNF/GkU5xb9drsyHOtjpcOGF37GF/To11ksgH1zH68PV3BqMPz4z5t5Cezl2iI017YC5sTKR1PxhuM@zaKxtDqs4t35uLPo@HaSmU6HEv46BGaKFeEbhovwI3SHza7jgUyiOiJKgaaK5bLwujeYsi3IKDQz@GeHBfogTQMrshQy@uPRWKHRzmXZdmKgdzWsO/Ssw@JKWM1gSfP8Vx6H6LxKJy8iegMQFPXo3Os0P3CdsN@BvdJ6BW0ImcLMkzuqMD4yDe0r@Ec1D/aBQGPLSaiko0x04VFL/nWHTQqIFVtO82DHn0Y9vrUvxscX0ERvHTnvG86fpjSCIZ4YZbGikgMRyKNNYCOW9yXdwWKZbxqZF3gxAItbmN5EN4RnZwMCFsmXp8HshEXdxBey6M0j/itThp0gnziiqMh0lIxdFHVQDg8eSzdT5cZzTNUwIu6nEos9AOEYlnnBPcguGcOOnOCOwh7GMwL9iEY73qaE@xAMLc5mR3uQTjXpOZEGOAsGrDr@cA7H5hOV@MG02hqfcsFtsYyGUnYkAUYrxheH8n0TJieswVeO5zZEuwF7ZPYikdAltZE48H3iFsoFI@q0DhfxPLkNGE37N7MxOQTkPiccgKxi/nrSwn4LIYAtD8QpWw6XGbOazssaIJ/DOh2LrC2gVjL7NOnuzATjJjkv2JDch@vIZznjJWQUyuCw6@iieqVJ/ooEs1OI0zz49JN6qBROWSjLEUihLetqF23HdAXIamOWk7kjUNKnT2JfOpBg5VD6RHRkTeL@@lYmuIeHHFSi8yyZuS0Hk5VE/keUprQIzcjYYH7sMzKFDmDMHYuGXsbYofUnOAzK8EzopV@bmEfVpoU4EeNmmhT4YLWAtVwWyA4Az2T12tcJnBgi@ky98eLc5wkMGcOML5f8RwADLYAB@zZpBiXfaLjGtzmB@R8obSSpSl8HuU2IpMUVg@h0z9A40LCiS57iHcJJEUSm0GaqehhuZFe25NNbqJ4XNLPLlydG42ln6QRRzbNT8R1T6CXLLMCCzfGVNjt/XLot6PMTVR9CX0n0ObLClnpkhMfwoK3cwh9L5Mli1BqsATFh3QFe//eLok2ec7ulKKli3PpI6e1eNueq4EhVpVkOOLMAcoAUJTjqbJC59qORKfY3Xo@kMpNNtLC8AofzhWgsleUuDjH4dw@dd5x33BrDlEkHoKWgqhh@hIzpy11W1CDZTrDOsdq5kRGekKbvvC8liYVJqEwEARpAQ2Rsny7UKhWcfUyyh6yE0ovuxBW1LLfrYDPgvCifgU8UPkUvIlILF1Qs6lgs4npN05AN0xROPZGkJVc3cHJIC59WHnSH2OHKtCjmYmkxMc9X7QzWMh56okT4kHdMV2ceKODtGhovaWif1gRGGcbBtrR/mGqg9sZswx8j7TYPXwTH7o4FcdAnTisdDnLpFdCbLa2VMwmOnrjN6mF/DDw6Z5f270Cpbo5VlLMdvkdA2W8pzO3gROxeM2mkCY0702TPMAmUFOYm@Ha15q4ihN3aau6wvf80aRQUcETImhevmtftUDr5xbxfS8Y0e8YBgsFY9gfeBQiMqK9geyT8ynar16gVVoxYhDobBGcKI6G6zfcd8znonJFriAV8fQLPQaijilJ4Kpnqor1h4iK@bp6QwkM27Q6iATy3ic@nILqIk6@VQJZ9biXDUmBi4Pg7HIr3j7NzWEWpJ0EY3qH4uN7ER3ch6YQke/FOEWhCVcM6XpeH5kcp9ow/RYQgBP@0cnp7t7xsSFOCOYrAriKwOeJ0QSDNgSKa3TFNCmuBuB2TF4pj7CwCJvnV42Ak/wlGmG2gkzYFK6RnJxWuN@TlyBXpLepYoTxdR6dSELLyeItQFoWhNV0H/QopF2UTIsly8lkMnKMFI/upYZpWWho@9LueYDxDt7RnStyWjyKyIFOpIjMPxPmH9Qxz0aIPA/PTYXnEuEGD@dIRbEMq@NHkcrxSGrqJop3y9QoWnYqryqDQh@8ot07hufH8K7cFTcwYJDmRJG3w6rkXBkGbCUCcrGQdzNqn4csJNKEDB6G13m44O@SqPkQy0Tcp8n88amICrLJxlWYhExwqeE6XX61cxRCEpbhthWeHOub2I43SjEhIsRJDsQE3nOLzXa7GkHJFKXEoTajbm89VQ0xJfVEm0RD57fBTjasGW0kRiXKM0OEG1FPAvlQ8EIMBMFERmOy5W7LxGOReBwDi7EWZLaK3ImdbOBQtMkmXsVp80/4Ixt7EjkZLzU78BHHfMQLz1eykgQiobugziZTUpoM/KHNPUWh7uhForzHkxBnC4lXHo5ArQ5dZyzztPl6W9sbuq2FUE7EBYWUFFN0D0MEpaMIRcm@86oQA2@V3@SXlC/NHmiFXXvEYrfIK4nFTLyAOIA2YOPBjywY9vtdR@ybY9e0XMbLWSyt4mJPBDGmNBjKARrg8PhZdInFR0hksEOEfI12HFFAgFdS01WmDO9KA9HadgDkwFBq7pjfsorbzEp8SdFmw4BfSk53r8eQ4DXHW094c62hyIVbXtQ2b9/uAFQgKLjn8yu5vXZZUX40dKzLnS9ZqVBYLxaWizGSyanqgrG8Er9ROwwoFYqFwmpxRVF2vP6Ym45olo6wVnIIMMteYEf/BnjTvsK7zJQa9BgUEY@NDGz/ym4ZinJst2gOuDkkiiAr4@XmdEoF7aNHH9Ct8DwhvO43yPI7fYHD8In9Mz8bwCLD5ayCa7R92@85A76S613xW93lunTbwzvoaSIal4Q5PTBRzx4AUZZ0lkSJ9v0LXEh3oe34QA1TXLlqNr0rOqdDkAH0VAePN6IFVgU3qSKEeGb8vsYYJpCf1TWdHrLTDARwF0tEAYkAFK01tOw7cVAIic/EQd4l2/KsIZ58YMqayYP086itQHO3fQekb0RgqhVKFsMdKvj0@cEJOzncP31bO95j4D46PnxzsLu3y559w06f77Gdw6Nv6GRU9vzwBUiXE1Z7tQu@r06PD569Pj0ED7V2AilVClBqr75hez8@Ot47OWGHx@zg5dGLA4AG4I9rr04P9k6y7ODVzovX0Fl/mWUAgb06PGUvDl4enEK008Ms5SqTKVE6drjPXu4d7zyH19qzgxcHp99QjvsHp68ws33IrcaOasenBzuvX9SO2dHr46PDkz2GBVN2D052XtQOXu7tGpA/5Mn23uy9OmUnz2svXkwU9PDtq71jRD5Rymd7gGXt2Ys9yonKuXtwvLdzigWKXDtAPEDwRZadHO3tHKBj78d7UJza8TdZAfRk70evIRIEst3ay9qXUDhFu4cqUC87r4/3XiLSQImT189OTg9OX5/usS8PD3eJ1id7x28OdvZOKkx5cXhCBHt9spdleB8KZQ0wgFoQDu5nr08OiG4Hr06hz3h9dHpw@EqHSn4LhAEsa5B0lwh8@IqXFoh0ePwNQkU6UAVk2dvne@B/jDQlatWQCidAtZ3TeDTIEIh4Gi8me7X35YuDL/de7exh8CGCeXtwsqdDhR2cYASAifm@rUGmr6nUWE@AF3cCsyqSc7NUnexgn9V23xwg5iI2cMDJgeAWItvOc0FzaMt5ZeaS250LeNOrfGIq5O5DeHYOd/dA4@Mn86mR/2vodDaSi3eJMOhowkB4Faug1Fedt@zm8OIc71nHoXmYjK9g94KLLJ5tqeP9NWfKXTer8YVySpBKnZ@/qZ3DOPfk/FzPPiRlAo37Uohd7nfF0kUZu57ZomF@Ym4pTqjtx@IsnSw/2CI@1/I4nHzQWT7fskUyNA5BwHKaSBz6BMBaKBnJasR0WSxLWmJOzhXRiWSTk0VyedML4Mf9FL3wviHmAcKZ2y3k8ziGJTTwZDkW4g@Z0KFr4uQ1sgNw2pSlEdj25YVWiGeHQ34xQaXLNBR3AMPAC02/J3nTvphInptMT8iiLQ8pK/K4HXkMDr/kFt8EyZioF8Onkml8ao8eusSGMgKlUOdZkaGQsD7RHvPkuH@bzxXqlfCoFjpu7WXtxwdvcTBXKK1UJvyfh/68baFVH54dCP1dndI16PG8wSNAA3Nw@AUkccZ8STWfj6UBrYz0yTAyngXUwUjXTgv6VOyqOzZ163gCET@OIZ4eOmPfGcWxBzH85XHt5bPX@/sgORHblY3V9bWKIk408gc/zvLnN5gPnqpP1AUt@toBNY2CYq1kB/Se/anDCGOnJ2LtYUQ8yFtWGnniJb/hzmSuI/Dzy/g0EBY3wBOcXDzETMVDmHyVX2O9oEh@ndkyBQNoiaLqWJqeOSIN3wRViXjA4ruQu2OqtRH@IOyw@csmHhZIMJBgMbvXH4yBc2FwQXJP3ZcGnTS2IbMtjGKoko/7prRB4oRBmUlWrmjjSG@Ct2O1CHotVjS2V6p2SglILExiIQ/BoyMtIYsjL5AtmHs64PNjwW/g/EYcvohBeJRWbXACZNwPU@bk4Yh8zlk0DAG5sV2FKnr8OMxpi@FEqi6Q4vP/yaP54q2BUOEGDWwCsLQ8CukchtAk9NO0zm44p@KpKQinIjhWvAPnziqOgFKRR86Id3lCH@OwogP7yOs6zEORUb6RUUJyJsj0O9GD4P9XpMkM@Fsw4AToEbVIDjvu0H4gJQkqpxWMXokozrW0GIuZqUXUjHt9E4G5jVdMJyyYMMMb8YUlIIGonbH0@IYf2arNIAAyOc5rxNsvHpBAjbhjwsjpKbXdR3yl33etXl@TB57KrmIKbiNLOldWmsjhi86X8Asslt0LPL/uKe2jJZmBAy6QYs0x@yJQOYxMkWQOFjq/RJMeYSsn1kQyFGULj9ipIJqWbPwjYWEU9TItGXoLquj8w1TD5RA8szEh8OUKiBQgZPsUL7AgG@S5jYjOLDda0tMsPxO9OJ5BDiKQ@mV2SubPgdmmMTN2RcJWGY2iMUuE80VLnInZtAfX2F10OXSy0Y6gMe0LMhPHTMRcZKhGSOGrG0B16mSvQ@xpmhL5NcT@tXvp4h0WNp/ikjGMxAmb8S3uBntp0mGb3YeVW40yzyBZt5P5H7hkt27x9UqcmqORO@SCI/0vgogioHFeo3YJ/VBEJdO6RE9V8qhznXNG8KC8cqLk8sxIGDPQicCzlP7buQMC5JUJG1imnrnhJFKZd2TVL6T6gi7edkPXN@gS88xVKBQgBz5oMCvUIEQZ9SY00pxubYRfYtsCGp@WQXO6vjaa5rBnum2z53THZHX6weu4@cAdBn28vl1V1eRsIB60gibogPvAZm8dt@VdB@wZNAecSDp59frkKDnxF5v52uEzX4x9BXmwZ5SzMgW@jXtSAq89gKqxK2wsbjfyo@kemicUMy00rTVGD9z44xMDQb69UDP@8tVr9qXt2j7og0dkc8leOJbtgvgAZYqsMIMOlzQYfR9zPxG5s33UXWhmp8JshyZ1wrk9RWQgoGWRtTRoioCwL46txrn5MbB6bE7QmC5wVK6WnFTqeH2x2wInTVHZ5FOc7WE3q@DZ2G8PTp/jYJwPzGluBro1OdeHc4lcderxyVoojG@6gzEQRZmcvAG075u7MRhttgCIynxy0qCuh1fftHDarxtAUfFqKiEFqAeBpmo7V3gYL03DPaSOyM5WTJtFdKuI/atZfjywFB2J2lOi2svimexGlq1uslMbeZcddU0LRljsZIjJl5dBD3zmBQOM@rLGWKFULBZzxWWcon19UjOoIeBXntCqKAcvjw6PT4GQ4ggiyRhhn4nEp0NRuTUWkCOHR6NC6d@jQJbxQWKW3hPxUAWX5ySoFb5ioZZVqHvLxOleKGGQVIdpShan5D2fDmbF3TbAQonmCLkG1yh8@dII5RSDnqWjYcXhrrxrCfGk3ZKU4D3i1gW@6uJ66HtKTH4gAOwR@UEqn0YGLXGsENRJz@6F2DsD2bubPIIyeaZsSDA@lwrMkc6mUUsC6ulxOC0bbSQCPJ2pF1xZPsgW8wpYDk1Y5JYj4BmSTXpYGrPpdB1oA4CX1fGww@HiSlYETUHET5xVqMbDswyxQyJcZpwGBa2r5fXCqBwrRQk32wn/fjC2PJa6gGE2jrSCvm236CSqYZ8ftYThBrTyLvQcfBteOTqDSUkVyG7SB2GDR96B7Bt2cW8@7qVs8jpXZGmAq@T2zdMODus5ICjRyYAaKZ6Iq80YYWcZrvPqVO0mMASm1ZEQczZSAoh@FhelACuob2IIchG7ZHG7T5fqe3KfJSakwx6DfjIAYfFVXTsZIMFj2YVzKgJn0mqIwMQWTokM34fE3Yk5sOQLlhftTnFTmsbLCIUb6yEx9x08opzPDXjswsNfjGxIivE1QpvWCKc2huI9lEWANxmzOB0TYoUHtMVilmbAzM2EuTwbZk7AFIuVB@4VbYjDVMQWvBT8tA0P5CMSIir@l54UvbRtr@vxBaaw9Bddr4nnYoKkgNzwMc5GFRv3phFYgtDxUL5JM3me55YskkBd7G2SugvbgvZhb7MtOWOxfebyihIBVd6WaE8Yo76LmhM58Ue0KHKqicNBUeuYOB0U0eO@ILsRrCpACh@1zKKWiZY48fgi52SSXiJJcSKJQC6ZpJlIUlKineATtYspUPTjM1kyqZeQVRLVAKuGFVRQeuaIj24KtMGPpmnwSO7EjsNSQzAIRqxbLNwziNEbSnQERmLZnuchX8kEjyy@1UWVjhQtJM@TGknTPRIDFCsRPqZjVlxNFEgXZKCX8HgNXSIjyrVFSdyYpAoLzAOURLF93KulxXPRyyzVN/mqIcYKsGOLZ10nGuAqvQp/S0wTGeTiyPJIeGyBEIVAeDraog5DWV4tUg4WlKhnpreYgIMaVLj8JpMx3g1oWqJdSckdwuTOKdkNoNCfg6OcFL6/OgC9jvtijxITDSeo8OEx8ULJs0cwPKM1ZgJB/U84Yy08@ZkRofQQyNejnBuy10iWYm7sya5kVpxYrxJS4a7IktghneZGnt/bEOlwDgHlHY8eI90LnCQWpJNdcDrgJCMtxRnQZnLPcriESpItJnR52uwMAZyscolcdqJUSuyoGFHCyW5ESfScCSbRYm94DQ77gh8UzAHpSiIV0n9ehaO5Y7xhz41X5PFEtc/jiBCWrPe72CKMLOv9LrbgkWPVfjdbyLOiQ9JS@km@SNQEJwEaJYoRA80pxWWQDBjFY40mYhFC40b8rBi7q83ANiZVxVynMqUqhSQSR8Ml86DHiFdMSmzkTrAjEK8e1kYjKi30cdal3QpPvBClD4dI22qyS@C1OXnQExZa5kB11NDxSpIwAUhsPgkmxsw9brtJJwal@YCFxqB4KupFJ7m7NwFW9ioFfVqhlKcjRchvzUQ@N31KVTTEKk/fvxNalwms0eDJ81sYW1VmrPgq92CViWGVLF2shpIkngMp9yBIuQdAyscgiYa9DP0lOVM@ngNs3wfi7GwaBj3ewUBKwABJ23JwEhvHwdfm@D6YC6BspcimzuRWZWGCSE@@D8aTSRh07nonXI0Tnh0TZ90@2r43eerZXMomeWUGRiFWqWm0sogWSW0a74p4UlWisa1x2ew44UggdX9N83MiRGI0Je6Ei0Cp5KlFIbCo/Rfn0C8bq9Zke@CIJ6ZhQFtWPrM5GEgIPsPEt4qFCWKCLDkOFQFJQtwdOin8aLQ6eboEHig/N5l@b0me8gmf2KRTEYrGJVaC4@QQLhJOsreS8m3W8Oze/FMz8@97fdBx2jMRoPg9nMfnk1ITIj1STSeG1g/qy2b2Z9PliuttE2e/PbyRP54qegmKjhvToVG79rXo/e@CLMoia@C30OTrkkfmIPnFTCRxod0Uk1vMHfaatq88pKnzFAY@@BhpPucqSirFahYMmcXJQ3QDFB2PbIssUQ1GRgjYsI/rNQE37sTGjXNkNmfgybh4uTrFNlTMguZoe7bpiqOIRId54eP6RRg3i8ej4@YuysFxLSB0YMemP9/zOz9atghBi@Q7yFqZXffI1XT5O8ciG@Uk0OK6pjZOjmm57xwFJ9RqKFZ5UlGRvIOLoUtcMxf6Eijm@uwpsIdoT3cpRMDE87IUA94J0HfzaHk@MYf9kJRh1TyAlLPUrXCW@wHq1vih6tZ/BUpOVqgScwvtQXSw5XuF2uQgny68lQdf92Yc3fLmdH8/ceBJcyxHBT3bXy0UCngIztTtdrhAgavEjpdPxs7jnHi@f/2V/6aZx6TJ@@xmXmeHOEBUjI1LE8gnuDQxhP4mdpwWzue4uCvnQ8Bj8hN4WozMOJ3QuP3NKTEfgUTi2WX2HguI5XvP5HXToDjyIYOAIu3NIDWqoVeqNJMD8qBHG0/UCU3SCBiNm8WuBVz4qG7fKI/EFY80z4fX8eg30TZE9bnd7XpZ9tbzu60Fle8OTSbY348nKPAoaErIG09A10NkmX3ldGNXZGAUxM3r2kbXu@B3LOH9uXz2k/Yy@XYfV9I07MeO7Yu9UV9T6@9UYEwocgaLmWFqA7f3XKjQRam0hH4/WH4gGaD9oNg9s69ZRKfJyNAHir1UkQswWsZLNLl1MM6n7ECR0ZhDS0TR@bkwnGb3x0aizkbX@OA5rgZFx2AFt8vR1m@qXirJnOghcdWzUbGNNCxwGAInPALxYSluK3jo1G//wdltnDnAzY00xxtuiY2dNxYvh5yMx5bFrgbtNjQvPhO/LY8ak@BIVOaKZKWApBEV69vfDkGf0dLtIM0PsENTm5OxayUQqZcaWZYeDtobaYDwO5VRkS1QND@gJ5pNfJ2DZr0/pHtSInlG03BoQDEtdzDBOSZQlC@s6rfXWq1WY4v9TIbVas/Akcux2rMa20WPZ8/YLrw/w/fH1dLqaoVbzu3qN@D5THresmcAg7ogvJNtF14hjK5awqEUVvFivrqYrSyeV7e2K0G@XnvWyOcvwPV3v//Tv/unf5KviZfv8eUZvdTfhZEMw8gvWjeLj28r@F7fbaQXm/XFfiN9UUEuQ3H/2g/MrhnbJmZY/yD34sqd85bOQKPVq9U0S3/6xF1ng8jpR068xCBKbnb7HZOSM4KwXU3X0o8fg2urmv5JWseTO4S/Gfp/BH@moyyn9WIiLS0f1052Dg7i9wSF94@2UdPEBXdTGKc5buBAod6n5Op5rs4MgzVy7H2IHhp0n/OISRRZGi1GOTLfCSRl6RAzCYCag9rIoUFaNVcvrq02cqlUSuVmag5hxu1TyQKJG0Zxc7VecEH2R9KCicLIWgwTfdEqc9s6gpEBiYjxK3zXqsbb44NM4aCjCe8UZzeM7rtV@TWu49j1erGrdfEMkcl718Nza6Ob1@nidQnQmjjbYBIgN72D8TLVCVoCMqxc8Q4d@HQ1vRf337AVuVYj9rB73fFFF6@jpG0IwTW0d6C7Lq5I7rrynEHMgads2m1cSuRthCgW2wZHqpaNu0tdC@froaN1u3gsLVeh5EXEoJMBh6HOIE62aOMuaq3rcuN7rw1OHS@NlxcuU71l6LgkqhNcF@nSoSs8vWxZS33QBvs8JlIV3iPDVSwDmU0Lk4dH0yaMfV2kpCUy3E0KzNqvo41csSGPx9cF66mdXq8H8oQzWWgMA/paDwd3ON0AxMEUBp3lCo1uzN533fezLmQm@z/KmmdX4ja@IAvC7ByxpEnZ8e20qs5LhSe/uuZAkLnvBYEjTEBEdZF9C99/6wPUs7TCMxNcE7@yeqlPBU1FGXd56@QsZY@A33GGiZ/mAblDIQU3JCKiWSTa9HGLs1TC0pXuLUdh1rQHjsU3IfHcF6SU69NBG@jLTySZmxGo5dzQUlY05XDGxP5OYWNJVR7BITrhfl8WDK1OqNSaRDNpvMPxleeh9Oshk4S1cxYRKYIYcgIBSBJF4EjTPoKCjxIM2rUvnEEiTZZvZxY7N3kpbiXpsbG/J1vCGHUnKItWN/LO6FA0vBf0lubNfRBHMgwk5Qa3W57Ne7Iw2F9wK6cwJS8SHUmxMc0foVyS6MSxhpYM5MNmnE3WEHVb2Is4AedjXicRq7KoFu7MgYALFLncWKI98gRASI1JmuTqeHPuBDVArE40g0gaFxLgYwyMzB3vI0lWTZCXVxfvbKeEuOQXientjJvg/zHzTVRl08dDXKHxQSzkA1AFIjPtJsRwrUhvCEHObIHXtlSBUQw7tDPIH3ZBp@bm36JniV@2HmUa4jGRlSy6qOEc6SB9eRRYPR2vy4mksrxR6kYydS7NT0W4kWcjxDmGa9RCVNAQjk/bioMURJpHvKuHvlbmxo9C0Ary9Vae2SCOPAgtwWWdiYqgztdsI9HQthxlfFRlt7MYRo6ZpeyXlBB6B5qixIETLDrrR8SL29fPIN0tTZnUhgPvYPAPr0PTXBlh47RjmuPQHYDWYILaKRQIU88LFzjrdGX0P5AajnXtQGXznSFmYINbUbheIkZ06svg4pk30grZM/VMzRbXNnWVxqWhlpayAtAcUpaNFsw@auW2GOtB/yws0q5sLtj9ptNqgT4iLiuApCK3MOhcgK3jjPRNKASDHHXAKol2W41J@CAHlUgegtbk7vvmRc8k5yvv1DfHB9A10euhy@vzBOEdQxeFl5ZSyDFvubUWKCDqLY5LI554UBFpitoEfcgakMIwsPnRBKESMYMA9hQBeJ5h@YNkYWNkiJefzxWEujX1plCp77neEnBb7Pf8DL73NED4/9q7ltWGYSB4br5C7qktLrill9ImP5KDA2mhBocEnBz979XOPrSyRQyl0EtvwYqU3ZG8mlG8a0oHiLqo5WtxbYr@GFA/jj@iieXClF5Sg2bOuKvcg4VAHzbUJyuhlyqYYeHd4de4Vx36uEAbKJhFV46cabgz64edyJ7z/qs9XPpzJ57N3FK/qFMdGIoLvdFD3KSqfVR9rltTwtE7GlHOWBk8HdFNsXN@0LjbLt6lSekgUCUURKLpKHscS6mVsAP@45gvUQkRMlwx/fkF66MZ367MDXP/jQoRKmhORdPcdMBfwtyJEa7wZ7tvMK@rTJqQHREUMuPhRDGZQ/Po55hmmEquI5jY5P5L4OsSmK8QZG1CSVWrPLbMMYyDNJ1eI1@3Ds0jTue95o0rBZ2H40GfbhSR4aSte61yvIMoY/uv5eyCnss4oYNK8yE9o6myGy2jjJqI5uA0EoOd2c8CfPVkxDMJhJyTVBxjnG9dkUja6wthg6VK/CbbPKXeypjM00J4i0PMNs/aaMSs6V5@6sYYEL4a19SHBlXZ3dLGJn@@0ila2sHU1pxpeiIf0gaamGxBmtsyWATqcw7U08@AYrtKOHHLr8GUA5CjNK5WpeVroUMSNP29brn5s7gE4CojwpMxCkQX/yM6w6bDxQlUZv/KZPgb)

AutoIt is a GUI automation language for Windows.

AutoIt has functions for displaying GUI message (`MsgBox`) and printing to console (`ConsoleWrite`). 
I like `MsgBox` more because it does not mess with Grass and is more natural to AutoIt. For example, interpreter errors are displayed
with GUI messages and `ConsoleWrite` does not work in interpreter (`AutoIt3.exe`), the script has to be compiled with `Aut2exe.exe` with parameter `/console`
to make it work. But even then, compiled executable will display errors with GUI messages. So I am using `MsgBox`. This will not hamper automated
testing because I included abstraction test in the test driver anyway.

AutoIt has preprocessor with `#cs`/`#ce` (comment start/end) directives, unknown directives are ignored.

Line 10:

```
#cs ...
```

Lines 106-108:

```
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs
```

Line 213:

```
#ce ...
```

`}` on line 213 was for Octave, but it did not close block comment as intended since answer 88, when I added PingPong to that line. It still works because unterminated
block comment is not an error in Octave, it produces a warning. Note that even if it was an error it could go unnoticed because Octave exits with
zero error code on errors - same problem as in ><>.

**Refactoring**: Changed dash/yash expression to `19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100` (118248359446856100 = (2^63-1)/78, 118248359446856100*166 = 19629227668178112600).

Answer (score 7):

## 177. [1L_a](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1L_a), 9814 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x             -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO 8=,_      x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps    # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]      #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzxxxxxx                                  #
############################################################################                                         p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>x._++++._+++._^<][4O6O@]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                        _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796los*81''TcTcTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcxtJkiD4Wbn3D@5LMEEJmQSQePANEJAgiiyxShLZJCVVNQhRiUQCSDGRicoESEAUy2b2znrnsXa329M71ttzO9U9t2c3Zrcfxnb3zHZtxuzMbr@uzY@o@Th2dv0P@tw9Il94kFT3jO2BBDIywsPDwyPCwyPCI6Kl@73f/CaFH3bk2pOu7Q7Z0PSHrO1Zl6ansacT9kS3/PXSqiQhVN3rjvqmM/TLUooVGbMcw2rDOxu6F6ZjfTQ98C8xNvDcrqf32bCnD5npG/rA9Jk7Gg5GQ@Z25kdbZWyv736wchizbzldABua3sAzhxS@xthrx9b7rbY@FbI@leDAg3CfPTPtT/1PQ2a4/b7utH2A3GDspev5JsIbpu@7GH2TsfGeaUwh3QJQ3bPcF/VXX0wFbTP2BZCoD2xzzPSWP/R0Y2i5DvKkwE5evT45mopRLLI3p/v7074l9lXOddj@yLiYDlplrz1ft/Vp/GusPhq6B8Np/3VW75qOzkratlaaDtxgTz09GYWK88hz2yMDWT3smUABFk/Hsk1fMgC8xgaiUmjoYCnmmXqbg0kd12MYhfUvbGYxYzBgLVvvaQazLYDdL2wxE0uTfYRwu@ez8aDPfKsPWHy3b8az6zPHNNvMH5iG1bEMooCZ46Hp@ECprzEL2HNl2TZrmzZEiMgysoCMjfyYFydCk9quxOBjDKYyEb4tmwDjmAEjzAEUNjLCxboBXAn4ceXpgwEQCXw8AcKHVh@qsjVM@8zUfQsbC0TxTadNPByEzchluhPPJbu0oDCB3pFHuH3Tw4LQCC/rmZ4JKPWwIitXnjUEFiCL6@zI1D126pmmmmxSiSQhMRdTGGJGNCrCnZ303uF@GoqSx9D0wVBKeaunP/pS0plWZcvnFfhWZbki7b16xq6Xz9DNWxAU98BTdJVVv2N@/uzMhO@42Mp3vRsJsErAFZvl3cEwr@cGQGBuCATmdXSiK3dZ0gZ2LGG2M1UWsQrGodpQGuzAYW@ylDNj5HkoJSKm6heQadt1usBPyKw3cpAfDtsoQBEYLjTyLDMvgWvQqqiM3Cvi8GnPgkLzsUhijYDLOmIoSDuoe4KjQbq@a48IDmL6Q6yAwBWIihgPOuwN6@iWjVEgHFFxqj3TH9lDjDNy2ljyIMvMtsYCMgy3jUB99xKS0wEpeUB76sdaIREFwFAQLmUVg374F3/W7nYBT90wXK8tqusb1nYNkso6EQuijmGFdR3dJrIALoup8@iQwKVuW219iMk7E5EEEUGpXrkju81cSNC7sqBp9fRLaI6djmkMTV7JuSDPsr5@wWWHxWsuZLyvt6BgKQFKm7KdY092oZQMU0pRncn1R8POFssN9ljaz79THpeVx0tnJhCnaurKcj7frUCF01bIC97St9WcN/WErPOHuu9abWkwGfZcp8RyBpONqjswHSWdwJHOpr1WWtVQpilqxaoaWsdy2kp6B@piDRJOqxWjajSscrMyFT2eJKC5QjTYXE3FUGUJRA41ist8X7ccbTBhb3LCFQtz/XNkOQZrMW9kzLTfJfdIUUeG9dLFCgJySPNt0xwoBa2oophAuLn5xoB5OZ3CITJctpqZdCqdiWedMEBOExnFxnpquSi27EEP@zBgiuMPQHx7WHcNHWqPj1J8CNpElrWoXpPoB8lCMvHKTHsma4EgDeoRNUne5DB@DgWlwBA1oWRLNtuxhgxCANry0J@RxrZ7BQkSTdh3gehwMFG9C0UDkXlG6jwjPCXySWbpwgGBgthaJtvKtSxoBNjcQKaLOh/LG4CvljgMYOONJCZ7@voEsBi8L4waDLM60Jb6IB68CTNMlDkgfEzeoWAiI2p/PuhPqEkVcqX19WQbm2liQy9fz/0YhPTH/K0tCTNfT6gI0PN0zCtm6053pHdRhXMgim4Y5mAoBBXkxB@CKJrub8gzJzpPze9Jy0@m06ZORHSrsTRQyPPSE12hjtJFKHE5G4Qp04UaytqWB2LJnkynDgCXU4nL7xEkQcB7eQEJgQYAlcwcm8ZoCFINKvBVzzJ6UGeROofLRd4JTScPXvHUQbLnOmHSSEyx9qgkafnQC8lYiCKHJTqLBzpXRFVLeFDhxz1ux6z7/TmI3ZBE6Ahivlpe16Du3YGz7zruHKTAyBAtgiRDeDmAJnaCWiB0XIHaRY01VA3DIoIyA6kBLR/qX284HPhl6CesYW/U0qCm5E@9ycHw0MHKkh96E2vocnfLdlsgln1on/kghbwxalnjqQyRX1iGH3zpEhSwjs@q0HN/O4Jap6Q7PghM8t9F4FiQTIKbUPBfGQAJSANGKR2fRPE@CJWTiWMoskZNSYNGJ2eZjA1XVsGBsUK@7Lp9lELsLSkGqOmBSm85HZBWQuaTyNfndnWh7Ce9Lp3WPriWo1ynl5aW0uV0DST70tJjcO2g6zG6MuB6TK4cuRBOQxfFyJILQxsUA/2a6ZtGgHmsNrHYxtgrfbQGit4ol1ebWb1RFM8SPlUQdSDZADqHD8CTVqtVdKqqXLuCjGqtTjL3uyidTwzPGggmfKlf6vxdcGGV2GD1B66HCmwFO9nbedKvetALgtJq9BQvfdYonDXPrs/ambObdBZjqxW92oJMQXpKX@t67gi6S7WxVs4Vm6raWIVOslVNF9IrirKVsyEhXVUfbqkZnXNbSZsgtZWzszQwVfCnYfQ8wjfOllQ1ZBXQgR0z6IRKWrvegvRbalPNpCGums7CEKOaTgNnDGSCT5nGmkkM2ocKuHvyIjGK7F@AeGSGb6MukfO4OgGv@RXu2aZHqDKV2QGpnA70l0ACdJftcGjjuE7OGZECTNqpG0@IBmEIQX7YeaBgtBIwiLhjjUHDh4Y7CTQZ7IBRmdmFYZ5rm9pb0i1kBjWfYXvV5qozR7xf0Aw/KkRQXMA5sHUDWmYS3ZnMzgAhVNR8fn6IWplBPK3r0LDkrjxCz2DoDvKvbZHaPbL8HrIXVCMcC3gd4Crq3NC5m8S1A2ZAp90FTptja8iVcKgIJxjlue4rKqp9da42obaGXT4SFQzZqT92DRiwmND1Yygf/bE959LyXAeZrO0BaqixFSyDKeTz2AvVqF4/KD1bzN95yIFjM97FGG/jWKeZa/gGyzuu7XZdtgIAWDU1jVfsA8cAEkBpG8L4kPnWR2JQvevCyCVZB03sr31U8oobq6H6rCNknuC1DyAs2PxMRwAL8nxy8OM9EPHF9UIB6A/eCvQJMxnDMp1H9DRYBCCaLTT9097IlEyj5zL5DDrIUo3l2@ZlHpubDD1RDzS9HGhTpke6RBhNzG5JQ3cESknbtK2@NTyguRnbwZ436lWC0F2oXhGCI8scSkJdjjpjnKaJBKXT5fB7Y5SnvmTSk706fLZ3flQ/fV6V8yPfy9tWC8qvbZ73QW@yTV9m058UOzYBmYj/8cI@dt1hlUoIJ4ju/KQwThD9xbPzFwdPj@vH33AiCI1v9Ue2jqSUl6cAMPoJBQd1Kjb31PHcfqhQ@qIglleR9WZiOhJHVyJ0DUNHYjIy5r@B/n2cYNQMqWsYLOfy19BTAG4iIE46asZgIHUzGYSkScjQU0BuEUqciNS8VuC5jZ7hFGRMZ4@jmxe@OJLAfF0s3CBy3xn5g1jOrotF8r8cdjrY6YTeJfK@yAEa0DZD71Xy5lOYiaQCtswEzQUO8a0RPj71ORffTNBc4BDfOseHU6bz0U2FzAMNkW0QMpxinYtrKmAOIK@WpyDQX7ggvF9YPk2Tx@upFGoJZ5IcqDoJjUaOQkrRlAPLXc6fK5HjiKgFQSW/cFHDjlznBa24jlhCFP0LezZmB/o5@kmAzhA1G8Jbbr/VoZ85AGUxDAchhZPByJUvcSoRZwpc0DrMKwKjAQUhA25Zjp4/pgcOLebRkxwkJYhpmZ0RdMh50PjQfQdYbnuLIDutlrUIFPiCpAfPOWDeqDWPbTDA6c2Mo1mC8cORN7TNtnj@199rQwHMFk9Pn5ASEjrOgW9UNzoLS0tExRf6mV@yBPNhZFs6sYFcd6E0dJy61O3QMR819icsl@vpXh/7elG4UDnxB0TQLfWMU@6Z9qhtBs/5iRCLk6N1Htux@pQjeKKySoOPBdGn5hp4fFL3bFdvExaulFlmVNq8XMwxV09iigxI@XvQGUwJsGgOHsa@wxH/xWn3u8rVGuB3PlfKyUpWWNdbRTPv@nrLMm@pB55@MWq7ucFFlzKNpG0squ28EeEINtex9QvuPEfnfAbwLHpWtwsjd/FcBHbVA6XLH4Dalr@ixy1VJejnGGku@m04PZv/LgIJFjVDx2I@WTb9fE6FpCpiQKtB1uKCWC7GJmuKsbbemuDYs/f5NQsTJAUCBE/VyGQKq9iFhROp0dLbYLA4PvZ7FH97e35svkpHCAy30zHNu1oz9EhWX7dzpXbMuVA4BzMjkWsOKI0Gcoat@1BJhoLN5iUUC/3cVnGxkzGwukSuW6ptRE4wT75oyjWKM7AM17b8AW9J4mWRlJyerIrQ4Fos/URR8W2Wv20Y8mAHngtd8xu6awxx2nNBPbqH4OIzjjinG6sYmruId4Z7hd@FqkPPvTT57/zO7ONcqu4hgnI21QzLmBO9bdxVXXHhjH7mc/FiLlVDw57rX2YvXdfrmY7PSlohmKLBVQvdtvkU6OnB4eI67Vu268MACH9v4wUMdHyf/86vzXG2WbqTo4mouHt@NEHUgGli3L6gMHW769obW928Dj8LS3zkdVCyi@d9JVookYrFOyVSqPi4TlE8F4ryC/i/qzLQZJeHs9ox5y396DzxJWZDF2cQhge4VDU/c/uFLYqp5flodFEBeEbvSp8Ez9@it1jE3aC3GExIbQa9DiNsb4Fj6HFV@rdJbe321Nr3k0kzaDfvykSscC9sEyQ0/c4UKSsVip8Zo1go3F9CdeyROTLnSozD1gcTjYpukRX3J6ogsrEs5m3ywDyctQmhPopB4b2oxv4b324VMLptQSO/U3uZK@8GoGsPcBx9BI4jdMxG7DqjQaJwY7w7HjnHt3OuNwhatttOEIkhnyuRtu7WkRLquG/Sd5Hqvtd3Yejr9kFncO5R/gIpTXXx3wRi8okwf7BwDtG7FW@ZhctfoK@C/gGlal34OZyIvJ/gKS0asxPw9jaMyhxzOMHfRdyeJ0hbrmt/TumAPG1bqJaBson2bXeV0oyuI1ZCWTQ74eNMR6uzaF6C9zViAAncw8HywoI@giwNqXO4TynPzGXe0mvFZjbvGkdCj02TP75nBO5F9B5j4y5qW9rmrQRzddRtmbbOH@ONtdvwbWur91GJBoGeSzPhOHvO58uj1ZvUlAgaTIBZVjvnGz2zb9LrLUq@3v4w8oPHQqCxi985wVqeZn8XxBtY0OYd/E3Mzce0oqHrmH5@qHtdE4cnNi6ZCN9FcjaYVJ7L3IO@3jX376xc0ewDmsnQkmTMOX8eosxXrg2Idock4SM/17kwJ37wnK8fTwwoz1H/Vmzz2rmBk5x3NmwtP3cu/Q61z@m5Padn9jxqHOHbouYBNXLILYpvywTQ39P9C7QLIpkUDet6fpy7tmvb9@EuykQuIV13/vzrHhritiHqZ@Gd6C0IEI87p@qg6yYmUR@@qO30zBH0UL47dAdmjt4Wgdo4qcN/508pHxymffbWMr02XxPFGT59aLVsk11ZQMIHP762OH/CqGW7Opqe3aLEA2eC532moAzXu6tX6OrucDCgx/nAHvn0QzO5uc78Kcoy2ydC71MXrCFfjeY11uy6LaNn3VV4LVMfOtZFXrR@8Tq/lidlMWXcYrln6K3ZFrDKm2hYB6rx8BN8HMxv99YLsR/gVn1kd@R5k7tlQ3KlNZxV5WsB6Fg0/yIWxeYEU8@PJheBacEtCxJiDW1hhSJdGvXmnFkA5aS4cDYoYR4iWGCvrg7v4JLhGhd3qhML5yfF8iuyyrBiS8jgPz2JcTsZz4V4g8Gh8nzU9dW74Ceoaj2z@ny7gG5HhlF3xKx3ec3BhSTfdq9iE80gEnRHPObWvNKLu9sTrYas37owUmbFF@f1w4O7kRm2NfD5L8t1SnNViNk11XkpfoNFeDtnTqAldO4/eOi7HtrSgraRMzzTN3ASHAU1F6BcPDluFwR2zmYRcAA7Ny@z67nz1JhkZ5j7@pXZ1dE054WFVjq2P9s/Aubppd37IP7RSPetH43coTkX5/QS731QvtS7lvE8MUURdeI/Nge9iXf/IrjqWT4ZMwaORWoG1LdbxSVfij6mjRWhCa6fFTtCwM/yhP2/H26ySZGRDhnkBgaaLIVmwiOUCUPX0xjBKYqeyaiqxCPh7GrXAbAAirY5oAk030HhM9vyhwRrdVijwZavx@VCuXjDqkwuy6zZ5FjJGHdvPKD9Ccc8amNZb1aX07lcejl95pRZIU2gpu2b80H1BFzHogenM8o6c3RugoXuIKcVbtrt92jbBPSfbeiHX8PojWSx63EDZW79forLtP/lL9tiNwno6j7rW9BogRG4A8rtmz336jFPV6ReHwx03I2COKBwbW4bndutM/8KO2y@icS9Yq/3T7eEabrYpwUvR9izxKjghYoDR7RLG/JC49S0XZNXC5FwGCvIlOHao74DGlJ72PM1EBJkcjbyIusZcCGYM/RQTWxn2QFrm7gYRpaENDKyXfeCbHqRkv/yl9wgn@wJhZ1XkDxtxImliGaDRbKCNwx3BFQHSD6anitAFGQyNMERzjtApTa5v4pWdrRTAGpiLrCTx2S4rfxu/YTl9lgaN5Kh9W3F6ijL9eMv3jQKzep3rJ83/@vv5dVrwTf5YW57w5ezLACp3GC9igevQ3AUmmby8lgW2cItS7RDJ6xUYlukgm4qrsDuvU@7najemVdk907WWg5KGNxGBP2dD7r5UCXUvNFUl5URH@HmToZsHXfbwaBRBxffH0VWhGjDjVGWx@wT62FdyRlo2QZvnCE2bhvoV58GRg6rcVOU/DOzNaL118uSVlqtUnaWz6s7NXJ5ZtvF7TuNd2fjUiF3Nt7ca@b9gDlnZ@OHhdLXwD0XlO/lR3lsQHuvnl0va7XCp0@@PmGyfJOucNsaaOXL10cHR3snp/XT1yfAzRue2dS@6/X1SFJgXSBDvZ5r074oYItnmf7d0iOUIOEbgCsKW9bZDu7mVFUpbodGoILVck5e5s4QBEah8dh3RJ8X3zdj4bMAQjJ1LCakKDuiiiTqTNqPS9BsULewXLC5w1gh5AhaLs0RhcQjmVWBSzng0j15xGZzyUvwMXlAMd7NqNtxzEMBvIogZgGQSWFamF8ezjM3N/M3/wA5HkC/9rvmmHDcmmOEuC3HABhFoxj79YMXr4/3kpGgOkWbYGGk7@HW6g61Lb6djtcuV@zcCiQTDZJ9sVMjlK0@u7R8GkRjfetgz2CDcMHmSGYYPkoXbtfN6rYPkrzdBtHUmgxRsoFI18ikjtvV5Rwmp4BZWtjRZpksIaxfnd3JA5LrygAp9p5HXiY4wuxLc7Ycnpn5H/7Fn/FthmdDcP@hcI8LT@Htj8VbB9z/PAgpFuHtX4ZvJXj7KX97l0dWzu6t4rkJmYgMfHNwxHwa5yOL@vo4lnvs27DvtBwYaVp94PUlsQ7BebYizkR4lMYb4DwUF7AdhTTKZUrP9JoK7owp5/OoiuDkrEbGX@aYj/Jpo8y3I9wgCl1JfmN9Y60Iw1wzdxkgJGP3LlobcYSqWoZaKV1ag@r7lsF2dnaY7Bu6bVY3Kpzl@WX93ar8PiR0GWAlrrU0GMSBKFEMCKuJaMqynimqGBUbZ7qYZs0KKCS8BKFPU8gBICp6O4G9NHSarmAVVA/HHA9J8E8CbQxUIYcscE2@TThAlANEHDduY5yu5ZH9EJpbxuq9Fi8G@S2CnSBYWZ5XyRrv2NnwzGmK7awMKswv51Q5B9x/NGePa1h76rObK5XprZGYG/bkxHHRzmwfqGVKKV9azRc31FibkgUqoBdb0CdACW0G2qBhWh/cgV/f3Tv48vDoZGaTIEGmp8HSLF3byZzltGyjGTrSU7U@YOrT/fzJy6f7ASvjVEXLNAgRrdVMkzkvtWlKF6T@lhtuzaZNATMJFQv3RUxzDbl9Ws6cxR6F5mOAu9ywZCZVRb2@aTR3amdOaib5T/M2Tqe0Faxc4Drzadt0ms2ROQeBOdopHrbha4HdckmOjgUIbZX5e@S9eJtfeHRHtNcvMHyTaBtDuItB0haYxEHetTxPija6ccICekHWBKQWkdQoQUOaWWqLU8NEXmZPGRFG2yGTDvlAlvYv6w6MYTzL4NA@CWg@3KVNtzDgORhGYyQYd@H8Eg0FJzTsAVERznC1LZoG0L3Afj4MOTH7Vu40oAcFR7R3T2xa60HebKtV0auNMQutvm/bwqb5A9saKrifbqzhcBJyo6iYgeIObkgbqzvbTbH3jwVb9DK0y@9oBPw6cgcsGsI/MwPXMYzi2LMRIIdqYLIvR32A69Dj2MRewmSv3BxEBj6mAyIauK9N5EHrt9chda1njttWF3oaRc2CSHpYLEb7A3Xc4OakQQ5zVn2B9kdxxnzWnsYYx/SGrllO2xwruBWn3ETugH/66u1lWpVn6gBtrBT7DNvTOywDYaEPRauNdidOCYTt7VAQJNvO9rbW8yW0yocRCKR4MvRegBP6UKXT1wdMGdEWVZ9pjF6VM8XJ@kNPZbka9mdXzGGZDI1d4EEBGqOYHXJZNk7yK3iig5KvQjmjr@@08fHRGrBGUdOa4KZEVLaMsw@7oG7guF2VQDWFKGVCCx0w/JWRoisYpSFF/LlMyUq0yQyg5gZTQ@72qAECLyjXrPYo2tMUa4Gcq9vbZVEaSXG4zaBa7MyRGIB2jpgLdFPgr7CrBq6hEAOoXRiUWiBQnnxlOg60VwXqTB9aJ9NHUMk8NRuccpSNTqqgFFKcxOfCUBsITZ5gsZe@tl3QZ5bzFRoBV26g339/hh1/R3T9k/x/n9fylWtl2a5O8qCMqTVluVctZlZXMpllZ0VZdlAdefQIB843y6DtnGuyJo8BKLdsqxWoz6AdVZedyrK@oyy3q6UVigGvmYx6DRG@8/Pa9bJ@k19@BNpEFnw83jqVZZ82lxY0rXgD9GELWc5noc5c4yZLOrsIk1@2MhmkQVs@RwK@y5@dZKhfOTvJ0xi9IpTcfLcfiJGkrhKWxMyZS5yBwrscSvR1lOhiMf48AI6fXzEn7Fbt@is0XWK0zGL6frx@JUPuL1iEQEPhJISMwnf3AgPHCjARX7O6qoIw@c1vUsUNGPU93lhV3Mzj9UIlk14vVtIplnoCamp@Rfbk67NnuUtm5tKNjr6ufds8ujg6@lo9U9g2S6d2D@XimvyObZfY/T6brLTgw36XTyq1kpdS@ZXCp818/v3796CQs0ZNq2lNtZFLNxtKlH5tc3Mlu7G1kn2SPo98VaVUUk@gqrAzy7IGfrsNX7dHh4wpKf55/JhSgiEn/DPuJ1IXjuAFQYRv6nPh9PUUO9vU9ZXMWumJUwHatvGzyorgxN8t@BbZ@jrbw8/f/se//fnf/oz@fk7fv9bZBfsIn4sOw39yf2zH3Dq6W52PuG8X9O4qyYTiUTq9vpo@eZeWUjUj9TFVLBZTE/o7R3dxnGB4jl7Hiz75YrF0FmUzxgXMcejNuA@L@4XsCJnNBJNSnwsnpVbY6sbSE6gMJvQ@@CmXn8RykZc3t2TXJa8e5HKduSnWPmRb1ayoG@McfsZBBkT6LMpTFBK9sbhXigXRWATzuXBSKjhEJ9fQO002rOMfO23h3/EQ/95c5N5cvLk4NvDv6QX@vWzh39EJ/g18/BP4U1F2RHUO38IKPu0XcDx8YUE7YJ8DJ6W@q1Z5WTBRJrOfeQGadh64zsPdtY/hswR/9A@f8BV/l8hHeBPI7GfpdxA6UqqRalR/t0@zKbIipXZ2dlI/6tGfh3/PHfxrfYt/Lz7iH29b95CGUuof8HNvfgwklso1M7mbm4b2bpypVMQ/6BeV8A0/3AUF2rzJ5Xbe1TKZBhVsoyZKeCfXrI15edOvdv5up9lYO9w4fAL4MzuNnR3tvFYb13LNd7UGlsQ1/hj@DT5KspxfOVtBZ3W8c8xRPwtwozBl@Cc@L3h6jaMX9d2902xpJ8dSpf36brZ08vppqoiv69E7Ba/i@/Fe/dnha4hw9GKvfrL3xcGbvddH4O83z2tPnmQ0EBtPgPhasyGlxg8ztUx1OBye//h8RUP1cptrmdsxQqY/53Nc4l1KPauNX@dzO0D7i/NtzOkxpZgDtjQ/MY76rHEGab/fea9kHmceF@zCZaF4Ubx46R5G/4eHYwiwxoUPrlfoFXrFNoh6VjBfFyaFybjQdw@LbXCa8Ffog9MqdMaFbsEpOMXiZJxAtfi/f@gOXx66gM2FmMNxYYiICx14dg8PXwK@DqT9Af6sQqEwBiLHhUv4L9hF@rw7L0CuVTyzAN4KhbMzqcHk9yZ09FoxrRXS2kY6bTXXNwbfnl3flDa@bdDQaH272aADKpoyy6bPzxrpZiWV98/O8lwvkktrcoUAbm7Oz5/VT@vn53lsOuOd5cyTTO4JfKq1zI54PE61a5XHZ@UcVsmgcqbyO4/Paqs5dG9koABK4LeTz3zmJ0IJz9rSmZRWrt6@fYvft1eXV9xFDu539jYMxZ@3efDiLvSCD4Lm58VPOuYIE0VprDevb0A/PEtX0kKDVBidBiMXz8alDivJOEpXtlVQ0ourOBTcWGdqrbaxDh4bW2pOKeAonkc5kweDwZms0bylRjbv1Wrd8/QJzlUoa4BE2V6vVs9k3Ts/kxulJsZdz21vMNfLba@qsqq@K@7sQBqYREkFbzk9ll0vza5v4n/K9c2OQh8V/1QVPVWoOPSsqQoAqOvwNr5W2I6yo6AfeGG865saOgnuGlwNRW2qNzfcT7mu3CjqDkdbU4FzDDT0f6R/UD/@//P/8jXzQc2/SeHQ02Fr66rSmpjq2oayldkWf9Ul4Kwir6ZXcUyR1tONxpOV1ZXNtcbj5gpbwS9bUXbOas35uqKaTkGDDhpgtZjC0kWRplWO5WJJTqM7laoY4hAc2@2y1e0Knh7HIKIMH3RJaQalWtsJ63FYo8dqDSsBo2JlapOpN9dQtykMRqiKWOQ9OxsXCiqrtKrL1yn9poJUyexGFpBB6yDUSrpCFgDytbyse41iU76Rl69bNziMXymqNIJbX6tUVta4e1lRitsbpe1SaXNjY6u4uQX68UahkGfF4lZpbWt1fXttbWNrfQOEm6pWKMGV4orAUwA8wrlVqZi@blRQaFVSQIeipFUGfE@dSdWW2YXkgS@DeHvOrK@vL@VL8Bg/3NgrjdnSpxX8NFagfLZKW5mVTPNJY2V7G4uriSGflqQKLr/ztX45J3MhwLa2Kd2U7we4d2pSoz/uNOnUhmquUdxYb@ZQzfsw7qwAGcXN1dQKhzaXj0i6rTxbgd8i/O8t4XFoTBowx71imwXWdm3cyux2Okvg2dN91jJNh/mmbQcnLl25nt2@strmkuSb8Okf6ebINK9Goysz/Oxavv7hgz6gz7jzwy9/8sMv/8cffvXTH371kx9@9fNff//zn8D3L@H7U/786b/bXsffX3//L/@3H/78V@D51/D9z/D9T7/@/l//Hv/S@9/A9/@K@f2N@Mbg@FcCXH/86@9/9he//v6f/wK@/0Z8fzH9/eFP/z3//7/FHzp/9cOf/g3@iJef/BS49Pd/9Uv8/9lf/f1//iX@/@//69//1b/6@z/@t@T4M@74f/7Nv@O/f/f7P/m7f/onf/f73y/4/cmtv9/fw//7fwSf@9N5Hzz3ydfn@nz/W9Hzu3AjSgXqANS0P/rhX/8B1NU/5W//DN7gPwz6w/AlEcJf/jB6AQz/y5xIf/Tr7//kL8K3P0gCJsIAyR9C2J8nwv7wh1/@3g9/8T/88Ms/@@GXf4xyKLe2na1nc8U7Ryu59XvAIeDGfeAAkIMssSWpRE/8EZ5siVzjFWl9FUegOf7JcM9Py6hjsrNP0jq8Zz7l8awslv8kQs9wU2ERQlfXKLQAunIBQ9fxNQiNkYJTRo@fJPR4TsjKpycMgCFyDJgAH3NChX/mU0KYY0wKXwoJh2@U2FIYPzGy3Xn/vlpDgCcQDF0k9ZI7@Isv4PO0yhgNSOFR22JVKcu2qng6EAJW4Z3C0UnvgAtPmq9Kz9hTHMej9zPgEJ8TYmPpPXuP1KJ/jYOymgTh34HHU46GsCGq7yTwynCfZ/D8TsCPJcKH/0JPRTd@gwD4yTDuB68ZRJIJ2MQyEodgYsg8O3KmOQiEw3hj/GcRIoEnIwEjMtn4ICxMIhN5SeFrZiaVkJ6psEwUxijNTBJVhs0gvC0w4S1NR2RzsQgKFoZOZTMInZNiEJqajRIGxRmUySQZhjGTmcpIGTQmXRGJrmRWyHZs5XM/giZKYC47bvnE@b0S5TyON6I@wkr08ggZgo3SJowK161o8Y0VN9ZCxKqk0ImKTKX5DHMAqpz00u8@dcdKISvL2eLG/PkCFWc/APYbt1yufldc25TgSe8jPNxRHDMIdRtP7Nd24AN0SLXrHDp30AnK2oZUq4mFRVaUaid7pxDh9JAVSwWNNQrN67XN0tr62nppdWNjfbNUXNvYXttY31otFAsbhfVSqQha7PbW9uaNVPuajTV2dPSjHLjHuVy@RElUi@ublUkVIpKXVCO9kWuXk@ucD5olknVGmuw12v/ghM41TTY/gA@THkjsAXjBBzDjMggTy88HhxWxSImmqqG6zlcs5eL6tkxcOjOdNkcsDWIf6RRPb34FiIA/DnuBVqtDl526Lp1Z@dQ0FkDs9vj9C7ue6/u/A8xT3bngQc8sPHbJGIZBz3U8fMHvW8PeAojXgz7axJvePxqGvX4LCMQJaA7wFH4823XnAWyy10cLcvky3ESBa5u0iwLAjw@@eH4ae57u1XefSxvs6eGrZ1OPdQG0zl7s7Z@Gr5s8NIi6HqL4Zu/Fi@lX8cARzhJb38xmNU2DH3xm6UNPbfldAFLUFmsa8kahtCkXs@cTE8Yv17ncTddqmcUNGLiuyY9SMLrCsz9P@OmmQ6fNxh2q89ubxc3tDdv1V7aK6fSpgX/SS7T42i5yU33LR5tkQHrlkEl4C49QHw0We8IDvdDpWd0eiJYrNwSApnV1FU4fvQ3misI5o7espev4/dwPpGDGP8PbPYY8DfKbCbFnwaXnMDbs41GhuONxiKt8VocVJA1FRqm0vbW@tb1a2spubW@trcPwcz1bLGVhfL25XcgWC8WtIoyqt4vZrbXt1TUQThC6vr0ppUAKWJ18HuRyUZbpaTkGnre2gwfXuVqvJqXaZgerLRsrbZWl2qHHaIvJq1tnBQYRZQnNSFfGVbm0hga2q0VWlCVZZwZL7e/vFvb3ZfkpvuDc5W5Bltv4sr5VKGw@lWWTQnZBgJYgUg/f9jZwklOWLXzZre/vI4YP@FLaQhyyfMFD@IsdvGwCmIMvq6uIgMnytyG6AiB3OUVbFGvIXwqFp7uyPOLkbcEfwNX52xoRu4cvGICR9nnILoTJ8hdBJFCOZfmYw4mkngf5rddl@YC/1OuI4kvK/DrP1Ff4UqcPRPLgDWquLHfB0fVg3C/LLXBi/ZVlA1zGRAe/Prhwj7cz1GV5wvOBOZHlMUHrxoUsnwf@kA7Q8/y53hu2zS7/TDz@NCDoAIKs8Whvv/XFF61ut@VN6ntfHFPQl18@1z9MRl6r2xIRW@fwcTEWBF30J9MfE4POz3V7ftBXEORMBZ1Pzk2i8Fz/FigTny4m1D//EoO@hKB5k2YCIXz6ANzCz9M@PJ/qLR4UfCiInuNWS65glcWm01Go4upZerRIhbhmaODjK/pjkl5llFxuB/SO0ZaaW3882pI3NuXyCjzlx/IqOKFpsEK6wJicPpNltbHdfCxvrsvl9OPHufSj4mMmb27LZXlzE/petXKDgk9RrzvKODuuFsAjn9/BBo1NEJ6gDoi@/NQcD7XnJlqWGLnc28RnZ@ctwOEOMNzG82rUh7HDFSo1dCJuYEp8Xn0K@kyh4uDGOhNfl8epsVRr60MdxjpPr0flsoC9qXSrDUTwCX92cvLb2lu5yeLprm8WgKrXjlHa3NlpXH1qgk5TLVYmKb1aLG1VxvjcXItrM8u27g@Xi5ulcmO03MgVm0tLhU/dHfnHNUJ9I4W55uIsFEgQCN0Rg28uJ2H4oCqKQWYKnvqN62xkyqKk05uldFpNVyDukgwMFvylpTgsx6AYZBCEUAzbJYjumcMRdMiFys1Myt5FGbjqoS0TpVBm8gZoTeCNR6nP@zyBsXi2vNJa36n9k5nPf/dP5n3m@@JH4mrgRlFK3UhtPDZubVtKXUs31zc7tSDFr9hkomeC8S57xFg3sywtpzHr6dXkAK9erXeP68HkbX1XSuVW3TU3tby8LKV2TmvyqnyonYdrNbU8LQSe4TohLqVpZ@c7S5nfaiEnp9We8PXcGijULC95Jm7taeMdVXw9ZWsdi6LL/FTmt/xAIlIVcEoVnP@WUygUDNsdoUXDzhnP0M53KVpvYUfXnZFDtp3ll6gkK3qZqySNJrTM715Z9vXWaq5GJkkK1LGbG6oXxiHZHEgpxxVOYCQMWobQPhXQqddlMfIw2eBk@93mu613L18fvj7cZ08K5a3yFvL9DGpJtpgupqEQn0Dvax3vSanBJ3e9@J3zZSVVHqRX19KrsWI7q6aCOq5g1VcajWKTNVabzQZUNqQX3qvV0uPi@lZmrVzcZGqqhhuwSpvIbnRBy8@tppopjmRtUwU3zZ@XiqlaXngXN4tqys/xN4iynvKl1NbL9zjfEtylZJXIlaedEss3OzfwX7thjZ2dGxo33QgH/tzc8HD4p3yEb/wRfWKAcZgo/LerdNp5qvldbof/7@DP7iHPqbyxLqup99UaVIV35@/OU1Jqm8klKr1MXoyAoCV1UeNacejP9Ff8dyv@SuSxAirkSvgGrzsrbL1WZMxcyefzZ@qPSqCObW9vbG2kpN8Ax26x5IbQ0LSxY8LIBKT4HNvGume91NHu0wntG8HxcvQRz81/EtyYFWhuDFU3NN5F3S3uJ9S5mBddNJf0m/h53GmGvpKELosuVmQdqoK49DSkHUNsBQ@swA21qnQtPQBcI2NIm9TgpyJJD3C3FL4qAVyWPfKHKk6eFVTpwQMhgP2h5g/PETlGEp65YkWCrgHYo7fbPqObK3DZlO/C1XHvkTvgJzvZE8Yj@XS5AFdDaQMtphsjeIV1OBWQmxVGKRLlmDme/AMO1hp1kJT9gxd7EAfG0R2yMhSxZa@F97pQ9pY6Kgv7EeABXm5QFZwicAQEdODJtQy1j1t9DWrOLMOKGN4ha0WAyrJilijJso6I2MDXJkRH9B2Qaj4g5qkrPAds5VwkK/Ig6KFMAAsxd9QdokP3ukZWlB6eetxoquw62FCoYCjbYaVox6PABYXB72KkiEa/Le6oqEZsJmzFZhaKtsI3pikhnPCJGHUjrQyz/QovqkFF@koxQBlyPaXyXf/RI@PdoNFvVtR@dYjPTKYPXfSFYnGQlWG1X4XqMWhYzcqwkclYzWpf/UrBd7wKBvtzodL5qsgb5NypAi1o/emr2Y8NJ/ed08zuN5wMkDzKrvy4@jGrVwuojGWtajFrZ78FrYbnA9IcVj9mnIq@A1@02E1s@gOtJKNXEl4Y5UKxqx8behO1OxsiZjL7kBmg02/YmUxThcRtCJyNWLEfPdIzdm1csXM5FaHerT7ebwzB0cxU8b2s6Dvjxx8bI4hfVuBZhWRsFYiHeILXNyHtQF8FeMzLNCKd00jK5xjI61erKz9@vPLjlerS0sfGONdvZjn7y4WoNiDxYyS@EttUqaz8WGVTLKFVZEV@aJUfais@k7NWJgNMzg5iMTmFKz@GkEEmE1B9g/KSbogLrMGxhomNgPymBzpPnTZ30N0cPl1xM2zjlmiIW/cNyxLgfC/7wDLbeFqt5Wfp/hedIDBMXFmJgWfjx4@lIGmx9wxSRuHSMpmO0wl0cZmHy9p0/Sk/n@Uu@TpPDAcyNxxG010kMGBf3Yg1VxJN1OB8z2ggCIqB68JNhUssvuMQhA1JD4Ah6YFwOZQiyCQhJwRkVQRCaQUFBLFQTnT42UJ0igrKJ9Stw5YPIoSTAY15DhlW9kOVZBPUJwtczNqh9MABTUV6AJlAGjAPVpPVQJCxR4@YeN2psmJpE/sCBEO4D5kiAs1QConfg1LAgVR@gDqK8pASAdoeYAjuqE0ktPa7JSQ2xCsQIfMhy/fFa7QvXhk5Pj8OAvmmcjKwLB48@JCprgmC4J@GJhAfwm5@kxLdfZntHr48en26d/yyfgK/MP7cil/xFFyfOHN52gAvRWtZDu0KNfTjovnNlwZjCo6/8HB0vB21zb58/YKVSq@eZfFoU2B9is@HQ4daDjGZPl0d4Wuu181fWRdWPnmtM15kSRtQ6RLpXHAXFJJDnbMdHVIRnVHh41wedObiPMbEtUt90/fFnXC54H5dOg2Ljuvo46kT0ArFHXK0tyfYnkCbYdBqIktbrDyra9GlqT2OIBGfbtMZ8ujUPiS8@43GwVCjpe2tQqHMCll0FANHKXCsBo61wLEeODYCx2bg2Aoc28JRDDAXOWYYK6@ubkTOzci5FTm3Q@daIXJGGNZKkXM1cq5FzvXIGaW2Fqa2sUV4WSrgJjVd08Ow4tpWEEZTDEPyXAc0xWnPNSC0NAMJ0ddmPCG9raTn5nZBJHSQP0SgUmkjegfpE8BWFU5VltOR5SnzN@EJfZXEh3lUYfc8D6TS3hgvu4RKp5YZbrqXJDwaybBNHZQBcwhaSnUf6r@plvlhNN6kHG28RwzVYvgO0fGuJYhTpPtaefWZE1yaF8yxleZi46f5sJAxsVMLBJGcynKip@UY1xJ@caxLKGCRowsgShwCyyB5zEGQ5qk3mpvk6u1JJhDOTXKGKI53fV4s5I1CyKtBVOr/CVs1SI/rKSaVNqgB4nZuqgNTBYqnElWvi2X519//4v9gv/7@Z79iP/z5r/7f//Q/o/vf489/AJ2FlUKAn/6MkfkH/PwrRsYeZHgSRSL41bL8wy9@Ca//079lP/zkZzzoT/5Czq6FiCAEvaKYP/9n@PMH@PN/ytn1EPDnf8QBMYqcvZESqpUCUD/9a8YgNcQSIvvFXzImZ0DBUETNa/A23oydYcIRhGxokKs5Hc5/8Y5D4HFBzciAV7wVo7cMFoAaQ@7peN101PZAneHTmCilDd3o4TkVwsv1Uf8xUIVxfa0L9e2qDUqPmJJIQ@5/n5VZOoMwOLGChzFVuQwX@Rf5lqNQhM3IeaAO70kTqOgGyJASGN5KUL9pJDDxNRy20Ii0yOuI4O8rvM4@6EDkoGbRhXiSSCuIjVMy4nJguiExGOpipcVuiB9mRBcDSuIghWIswYS4mSo2SGXaB4aM0fEm8ajkYfYHUCQQLeQ3MhZfiAvZaXRRyYlms3e4P9Vg8NMCFfMiLpHChKpMlu@ARU4LeBU1rtUkPKdXADQK5dVm4rCUecDy119/LUsxvwLWIa@tEIZYprjICIOKyaBSLKgUCwKaOU6SNeul0hQN1HGgXEweDMSjxURUMlpUubDlBOWAZMBYkE@IZjv2yO9VZ1GTRE4Ku1nkMZTFZlW0kzOHZE6NyepMBMCZjFOdLsv5qAszMLMFNT8mcjvhkyitxZgScWKNgrgnTXMpLLni9rySSyZ4C@piM3PPhEqF3zGh3D0T2li/O6HpYsW4CfSL@Xu32AnERCjhI2S84acSHRR2jb@AqheJI6TYI6eiwpCnLoY8rSuXKXNugQb/fHCWeeLqZy92wjkOYl65Q77sxZ4MXBhyuKgFx26afy3AE8MOum4eRmquZ/rxQ5AsfkyEk8ZjuAy360CvlsUz1S1xrzkaF/ADF5P9StizCS0Uj62FoQ@i5oxCzfP83HKs4fk5KJ92R40YiK@agXv305IBEcEVi6@Equ3hQHHxboihejdO0nd5tFPLuFAOByIwDYnUGQzoDNOGwRfr4Q23vstZglnkd96CRtoaKnSAa8/tu13TcfEEMow9hf4gwo0E6YMB0ZJlepYZMYrEIFoxsroqon712VHZVyW8ozmIX0oiSDAjy7xpHiNnvTnJnS9MjkcL0jv5fHpP4vSe3E5vx/L84TTN5ImzPfj8vKRXlQgDAEZkrN5NRlYcOjhDToKU0BtvV@cR7k1im2yf2khpHUDrAlzrQP3Ihm8@7dIXhL9ZxP/bCzCIvnff4iNl9mQC8qZPlyHTEM0PFtwVAD9Q1cicMZZcWLWf3TMtMdChEV6WySS4HDwCAhrmYGA60X28AeI76jxaPc3UezKFqvLAOTR5l1l2UVpcRM/O26atT8y2IiCzMbxBjo9NvU3y6n4ZR0FHQg/GADSRWcgWE6oYHdVDQOUFVUbPXqrq4mrFQayw9tBiHFF4sJh/NHE3LZpxErTK10BcDyRoik7zpDNUB5PBhB/vZdO5e4Ec5f0PL8lXeOrZnQwBPvArp4vZKFn1NvF5rIRZukePEMJqySzTIRlBt@WCNj5Thp/HortzSrMMYaRqUMoJ7WRRiVu3lXisVgR1kmsl96uSd1W6e9e5WFXjyCIRtvt5XcgM5l3dtg1DiWPkPreWmOvMyAT0wxJznQW9yvkcgRrGJEk3xLssq1y/UCULnAfwvITnG3giQhiDnvMKFeQN9dpgyotC@vogprUIn4aBumiMi2p8HTEGJQVunMi9CdM0FqZpzKRpJNIMW0AyyRiQZCSSFKWAxXNbEdhmZ7hAOmMQjtzhcZvYho/j6h6uvV6nrXTZyrL0ZboMAjltpst7CgjldDtdfkYOP10@IcdFuvwVOKK2lf6ULgfNAgE8eCXHE/QXIhzfjXR5V1FvpCEeZRykq6XLYZkCzGP@Shy54dOrLbHq74azqqaZ5UpllmGN8eHhYrYazSx9C/BPoOKIbAhcqrLSCgHjACTRacR6DJ4OdBua7V6ZnjKv@ygHU1NifiOaQ4HwTDU2qYK1ZETyKJ1KJ4URJwxDafIRnkAgys3yfIpYcWZkdhc5InWooVTIyfSJexrpA22FwhsAHJ/EsaP4QXklUfACvB@dGHkRnTPkBMkRRWgMoM4hC5n6Pn1LprCsp45b5qUfL6HZOQIsxFwAwkuJ0MZkOuhwqJtSYgN3kKwkFIqrfVY8Dn5Eo8TaOxWNpIJomQuCyVvkDAVDvPGrt2UnFg9JS4ggDGwUmryVhf0CyWIMimRdTFPljQ9IiMmcNp1/aGK1fSacBMfFTZb6ikXdUBCXJ0mSKykmIbKGRx6M9CFPPVqXwYMQPm/4GsQc440QCiKIxQxT4fLV/Qz93eX6e6BQB0yYSmCeYj2/K51Vr2/tZacot6NkZwsQA7PsmTpXOQpTiFgOo4OYZn5bXZtR8fHac67k80RD7FPafsC2cExwB9@mxxYcF2oJ3mXS8wInZi9Kixk1q5HYl1qgtGiYksDDMx5SGmXtdlp5xucVMYZgHw2Pzy5gL1nA8cJDfJQBb4rlvJV7I4fMq6K2TafYRSsXfNXBRSux8PDwmCeIe7JfC020wOPw/PjZ4asX30Cnu7m5qc4uRWCrhbhRPy7dukwQDltKWTz/FbfNke1Ez/WGS2eOPGtSRh6gDOi0bsOrn2jjqpBlMXk@1XYhHoeNcVTguoiagZ6QSqjq6NhlW4Kv/K49ZUUXSAL1FvidpdEarhph7cAFnfNz6r7Oz9E45/xc9GJYNOEy0m9STJx9GNlrgCthzUQalz9zyCJOAIz6tDEqmIATxydyO5QU4DkYBrHDWCNnaAXGDjg/RBsmg7V8ZbWIsxMHndCH6ECjDKW0hkPY0jqeIMNjITROfJJppUhniSs6eIuIP3AdOgeeztYltR3vNPGDqVcie@Rc6WQGwlOhg29iFHGDrGBdzHX4BR8@j4s7M2kKOeBNlpldjVZ8Stsw5LiwBvx48ND0w1cpEhFMNlrA45Zt9oGkE6i7c2aTX1pQKr19q9uFipQXF0hyA5dTHaLm3E5uNzj2MsXe6LbVDi5gEDZhdPmJmAcGdiqJc0t9VtoAbWo7C5yNvsBYNJNheDZpgYy0CAq@m/DY5M6tbCzukjJRk89i8FER35JyjiXLt8NbHl4Weak7MT7T51N8alosWpIciK1cBidlSuLI5CqtU2poozZQ5JQcHKGJTm42odtGcKKngmfJlqUHDgketABjBretAQXXQaWNltfU0CTVYQ/Zakmia19cmlzmyQIOvrKXwA5hEBWJ5dZ9QsDID9vyQ1xMlB6kUBbyuobxg6qMbrqKIarLbEmg4wsq2JR5Ewhe1mMvqzDUeDAn4SVFzgCWjKzKCUwAL1Y/HnDJOxsVhCKIh881xTY9zyEw6RJECaObv4UZceUWw16y7EXzwYRdLw6m4oaaHWG/xq/Ly8qv0QKrzBOhvkPDE5JRdFemZXeuGJhr0gPtpNkKbTjuJDoa2cPIIRlLlnMbAdSjUA1FOUPmXw/9MnyBhmyAEthEFgsK8Ua9kzbiCNpR4@EVhWYl1qUoxTg1SGDHB4HSAX5m5YdotfoIIlIXC/2dOk9tKlQS8YE4f@CQJbec02SKKqyOEVMSBS9N9A9tXyUyeA8E1y13Puj54lZhY5vsp5mTHWb7je1mdsWoyswcWrrT90feVfui6/YuQVlggw@tsTH5@C1j62sMN5iUHvEN@sWNap724G/SIRbbBdrcERyhQcc8nMmM0aZfPJAjzVi44aiyhDvz4ZPFn7JcmamlbKUf1EJuRN1vbDSrTrVQ6TecZsXJZNRhpjrMFDMKejwqqhWQtHzapTFsklVkfoW9DEwX8URknFt1O@zIdYyem/YZ3bkbX9OjfWRBA@rrg3h7uoRRh@vFfTpYn/R@oiHOetFVdFMxLTeAG04GJorG0OrTxgvL8efBaGOtMhuOOXzwAE2UK0I3jWfgWhqMWrZlgAwifqKKgeaK5bIwujcY1lsQUOhncU9OC/RACgZXglDDHUxEZIuDnAd52YmhrCnYd6nZ@0AGUC2ok@d4f4UHYByEszcBzgA1dT0qpwrdL0wn7Gdwn4RaQStythSEBTsqEB7rDe1rOAf1j3ZBwGOHCVCyMWaqsOgl34aFRgWkqtXSPOjBh1F/QP27xukVHMHLuc4HuuWFMTV/hDcAKqyIzLACorEE0HGD@/IuQbGMF01QFjixQIvbmB/Ed0QnrAPBho53l4JsxMUdxNd2Kc4DfvubAp0gn7jiZIi4lA1VFDUwDo9YSw/SZUbzDBXwoi6nEgv9AKGY1wXBfQju68PeguAe4h75i4I9CMY74RYEWxDMbU7mh7sQzjWpBQBDnEWD6no@dM@HumUr3GAaTa1vuMBWWCYTMDasAowXDC@PZHwmTM/ZEi8dXtkS1QvaJ1UrDoBVWhGNB9@j2kKheBCHwutFLE3OE3bN7kxMTD4Bi88pJRC7mL66ksDPYgRA@wNRymbDg8R5aYcZTdQfDbqdLpY2MGuVffp0G2WiIibrX7EZ1D5eQjjPGcsh51aEh19ZFZUrj/RRRJofR5jmx6VboING@QgaZSkSIbxtRe26Y4G@CFFV1HIibxxSquxx5NPwm6wcSo@Ij7xZ3M3H0kztwREntcgsa0VO4/5c1bHeQ0wdeuRWJCxwH5ZemWGnH0LnktA1gA65OVXPjESdEa30czN7v9ykgD5q1MSbChe0BqiGNUHgHPJ0Xq5xmcCRLafL3B8v2LKSyKwFyPh@xXNAMNwBGrBnC8R40CdajsZtfkDOF0prWZrC5yA3EZsCYXUfPv0DNC5knOiyR3jnSFIksTmsmQEP8438qk03uanscUk/P3MNbjSWfpxGGtlsfaJa9xh6yTIrsHBjTIXd3C2HfjvOXEfFl9B3fGWxrAgKPaiJ96mCNwsYfWclS2ah1GQJjiMJJBnu6JJok@f8TilaujgPfIJpLd62F2pgSFUlGY40c4RBACjK8VhZoXPVItEpdreeDwPlJhtpYXjVF68VoLJXpLg4x@HcPnXecd9waw5xJB6CloKoYXoBZVYn0G1BDQ7iacY5FjNnMvIT2nTXddtKoDAJhYEwBBbQAJTl24VCtYqrl1HykJxQellXWFEH/W4FfJaEF/Ur4IHKp6ibSMRKl5pNBZtNTL@xfLqJjsKxN4KkgtUdnAzi0oeVp/0ROlSBHsyNFEh83PNFO4OFnKeeOCEe5F3dwYk3OiaMhtY7MvqHBYEwNRhoR/uHqQxu5swy8D3SYvfwdXzoYlUsDXXisNCDWSa1ElKzsyNjMtHhG79JLeVHvkeXrJvOJSjVrYmUYqbDr@Qo432@uS2ciMXreIU0oXlvmuSBagIlhalpjnmliCt7cZe2rEp8zx9NChUlPCGC5uVt87INWj@3iB@4/ph@JzBYKGijwdClEJEQ7Q1kn6xP0X71Aq3SihGDIGeH8EQwCq7fcN8Jn4vKFbmCVMTTL9QYigbGJIErn8kylh8SKubrGk3J10zd6CERWPc@8eEUFBfV5BvJD4oe97IhK3BxEJw2t@Id0NwcJkHaiT@hd8g@vhfRwX1oChHrvRinSDThiiG26w6wkuNUG8bfAQZwxj84OX22d3ysicOR@YoAriLweWI0waANgeK6bTFNiqsBuB2TF8oDzCzi5ulVI@Qkf4lHmKxgEzaFK2Qn5xXu9@Q5yBXpbSYbIbzKwYkltJws3nzkZUFYTQ9Aj0LeRdGUWLRcEC0AjrHiwZ3c0A0DDW1fmn0XKN6la@SLnBcPInagEzkSpJ8J0/cbmGYzJJ6H52bCc4lwjYdzoiIozeh5EVA5DiSnriO4GyZHYNmZtKoMMn3winbvaK4Xo7tyG6yvwSDNioBrYVHyWhkG7CQCcrGQd3NKn4csJeKEFTwMb/BwUb9LouRDKhOwT5Lp41MSBWSSjaswCZmqpZpj2fwK@CiEJCzDbSs8OpY3VTveKMWEiBAnORATeB82NttaNcKSKQYSh9qMXNt5ImtiSuqxMk2Gym@Nnm5Yc9pIjEuUZoYYN6aeBNKh4KUYCsKJFY0FLbcWRJ6IyJMYWoRaCpKVgp3YyQYOWZtu4lWcNv@EP0FjTxIXwKXmBz7glI955vlKVpJBJHSX5PlsSkqToTcyuafI1C29SJT2ZBrjfCHxysURqNGja8@DNE2@3tZxR057KZQTcUERSIoZvochgtMRQDGovouKEANvpN/kV6Qv9D5ohbY5ZnXUqXU6M0lKLGbiReU@HjmGR1syfzQY2JbYN8euaLlMnChUWsfFnghjTGnQpAM0wOHwWXSJxUeIpLFDxHyFdhxRgI9X19OVxwzvVATR2rEA5VCT6s6E38aM28xKfEnRZCPcJ48C2IZhX4wIXnK89YQ3XGtSsHDLs9rh7dsZggoEGXdpTyluZS9L0o9GlnGx@wUrFQqbxcJqMcayYKq6oK2u0aXOgYoUBJQKxUJhvbgmSbvuYMJNRxRDRVxrOUSYZS@wo38DddO8xDsPpTr0GASIp2H6pndptjVJOjbbNAfcGhFHsCqPfJOfUkH76NEHdCs8TwivBfez/O5vqGH4xP6Znw1gkOFyVsI12oHp9a0hX8l1L602MjBYl@64tu1e0UQ0LglzfmCkvjkEpqyoLEkS7fsXtJDuQtvxgRu6uJpZb7mXdE6HYAPoqRYeb0QLrBJuUkUM8cT4va4xSiA9w9atPlanOQTgLpaIAwEBkLX2yDBvpUEiIj6ThuDO6bZrjPDkAz0omTxIP5faCjR307NA@kYMplKhaDHaoYBPnx@csJPD/dO39eM9Bu6j48M3B8/2nrGn37DT53ts9/DoGzr7lT0/fAHS5YTVXz0D31enxwdPX58egodcP4GYMgVI9VffsL2vj473Tk7Y4TE7eHn04gCwAfrj@qvTg72TLDt4tfviNXTWX2QZYGCvDk/Zi4OXB6cAdnqYpVSDaFIUjx3us5d7x7vP4bX@9ODFwek3lOL@wekrTGwfUquzo/rx6cHu6xf1Y3b0@vjo8GSPYcakZwcnuy/qBy/3nmmQPqTJ9t7svTplJ8/rL15MZfTw7au9YyQ@kcune0Bl/emLPUqJ8vns4Hhv9xQzFLl2gXlA4IssOzna2z1Ax97Xe5Cd@vE3WYH0ZO9HrwEIAtmz@sv6F5A5SbmDK1Auu6@P914i0cCJk9dPT04PTl@f7rEvDg@fEa9P9o7fHOzunVSY9OLwhBj2@mQvy/C@F0oacAC3IBzcT1@fHBDfDl6dQp/x@uj04PCVCoX8FhgDVNYh6jNi8OErnltg0uHxN4gV@UAFkGVvn@@B/zHylLhVRy6cANd2T@NgkCAw8TSeTfZq74sXB1/svdrdw@BDRPP24GRPhQI7OEEAwInpvq1Doq8p11hOQBd3QmWVgpqbpeJkB/us/uzNAVIuoKEGnByI2kJs230ueA5tOS/NXXK7dQFvdpVPTIXcfgjP7uGzPdD4@Ll8cuT/GjqdreTiXSIMOpowEF7FKij1VedtszXqnltOx8WheRiNr2D3/W4WT7dU8X6eM@m22@T4QjlFSKXOz9/Uz2Gce3J@rmbvEzNBxl0xxC7326BUkUfb1ds0zE/MLcUZVXskztLJ8oMt4nMtj8LJB5Xl821TREPjEEQcTBOJQ58AWRslI1mN6A6LJUlLzMm5IjqRbHqyKFjedH34cT5FL7xviHmAcOZ2C/k8jmGJDDxZjoX0QyJ06Jo4eY3sAKwOJan5pnnRVQrx5HDILyao1CAOwQ5hGNhV1Duit8zuVPTcdHwiFm15SFkJjtsJjsHhl2Hjm2AZE@WieZQzhU/t0UMNqKGEQClUeVJkKCSsT5RHPDru3@ZzhWolPKqFjlt7Wf/64C0O5gqltcqU//PQn7cttOrDswOhv2tQvCY9njc5ADQwC4dfwBJrwpdU8/lYHNDKSJ8MgfEsoB4CXVlt6FOxq@6Z1K3jCUT8OIZ4fOiMPWscpx7E8BfH9ZdPX@/vg@REate21jc3KpI40cgbfp3lz28wHTpzF7kLWvSVBWoaBcVayS7oPfszhxHGTk/E0kNAPJ88KDTyxMvAw53JXEfg55fxaSDMro8nODl4iJmMhzB5Mr/ufkkK6uvclikqgJLIqoq56etj0vB1UJWoDhh8F7I9oVIb4w/iDpt/0MTDDIkKJKqY2R8MJ1BzYXBBck/eDww6aWxDZlsIoslBPR7ogQ0SZwzKTLJyRRtHehN1O1aKoNdiQWN7pWKnmEDE0jQVwSF4dKQlJHHk@kEL5p4W@Hwt6hs4vxGHL2IQHqVVH54AG/fDmLngcEQ@5ywahsDcrFWhiB49ClPaYTiRqgqi@Px/8mi@eGsgUrhBA5tCHFgehXwOQ2gS@klaZde8puKpKYinImqseIeaOy87AkslOHJGvAcn9DGOKzqwj7yuwjSkAOSbACRkZ4JNvxM/CP9/Q57Mwb8DA07AHnGL5LDljMx7cpKwcl7B6JWYYl0FFmMxM7WIm3GvbyI0N/GC6YUZE2Z4Y76wBCwQpTMJPL7hR7YqcxiAlRznNeLtFw9IoEbc02Hk9ITa7gO@0u85Rn@gBAeeBl3FDN5mlnSubGAihy8qX8IvsFhyL/D8uie0j5ZkBg64QIq1JuyhL3McmSLJHMx0foUmPcJWTlUT2VAMWnhUnQqiaQWNfywsjKJeph2E3oAquvgw1XA5BM9sTAj8YAUkECBk@xTPsGAbpFlDQufmGy3paZafiV4cTyEHEUj9Mjsl82df79CYGbsiYauMRtGYJOJ52BZnYrbM4RV2FzbHTjbaETamPCQzcUxEzEWGakQgfFUNuE6d7FVIPU1TYn0NqX/tXDh4NYfJp7gCCC1xwmZ8i7vGXup02KZ9v3zLUeIZZGstmf6BQ3brBl@vxKk5GrlDKjjSf@hHHAGN8wq1S@iHIi7pxgV6ykEdta5y1hgelFZO5Dw4MxLGDHQi8Dyl/2bhgADrypQNLJPPnHASqcw7surDQH1BF2@7oesbdIl55ipkCogDHzSYFWoQkox6ExppzrY2oi@xbQGNT8ugOV1daS191Nedjt637AlZnX5we07ed0b@QBtM8LLR5GwgHrSCJuhA@9Bkby2n7V757Ck0B5xIOnn1@uQoOfEXm/na5TNfjH0JabCnlLI0g76De1J8tzOEojErbCIudPKi6R6aJxQzLTStNUEP3PjjUQWCdPuhZvzFq9fsC9MxPdAHj8jmkr2wDNMB8QHKFFlh@j0uaRB8H1M/EamzfdRdaGanwkyLJnXCuT1JJCCwZbFqKdAUgWBPHFuNc/MTqOqxOUFtNsNRvtrBpFLPHYjdFjhpisomn@LsjOyshGdjvz04fY6DcT4wp7kZ6NaCuT6cS@SqU59P1kJmPN0ZToAp0vTkDZB919yNxmizBWCUFrOTBnV9vNGnjdN@tg9Zxdu4hBSgHgSaqmld4mG8NA13nzIiO1sxbRbxrSL2r2b58cCB6EiUnhSVXhbPZNeybH2bnZpYd9mRrRswwmInI4y@ugp64FPXHyLoyzpjhVKxWMwVV3GK9vVJXaOGgN/ghFZJOnh5dHh8CowURxAFFSPsM5H5dCgqt8YCduTwaFTI/XsUyAE8SMzSe2IequDBOQlyha9YyGUZyt7QcboXcugn1WGaksUpedejg1lxtw1UoURzhFT9KxS@fGmEUophz9LRsOJwV961hHTSbkmK8B5ps6Fe2bge@p4ikx8IAHNMfhDLo5FBWxwrBGXSN/sh9dYw6N11DiBNnykbMozPpULlSGfTqCUB99Q4nraJNhI@ns7U9y8ND2SLfglVDk1Ygi1HUGdINqlhbvSWZVvQBoAuo@dih8PFVVAQNAURP3FWohIPzzLEDolomXMaFLSuttsPQTlVkhRuthP@A39iuCzVhWE2jrT8gWm26SSq0YAftYThGrRyG3oOvg2vHJ3BJKUKZDfpgbDBI@9A9o1s3JuPeylbvMylIDdQq4Ltm6c9HNZzRJCjkyE1UjwRV5kzws4yXOdVqdh1qBAYV0VGLNhICSgGWVyUAqqgvKlCkIuqSxa3@9hU3tP7LDEiHfboD5IBiIuv6prJgAA95l04ZwB4Ja2GBExt4QyI4fuQuDsxB5Z8wfyi3SluSlN4HiFzEzVk5r6FR5TzuQGXdV38RWAt4BhfIzRpjXBmYyhevVkEfNOQxVlIgAoPaItBlubgzM3FuTofZ07gFIuVB84lbYjDWFQteC74aRsuyEdkRJT9L9xA9NK2PdvlC0xh7ru228JzMUFSQGr4mGSjgo170wgsweh4KN@kmTzPcyfIkiBd7G0KdBe2A@3DrLGdYMaidubwghIBVd6WaE8Yo76LmhM58Ue0KHLKicNBUeuYOh0UyeO@ILsRrSxQCh@5zKKWiZY4cXiRcjJKPxGlOBVFEJeM0kpEKUnRTvCp0sUYKPrxmcxZoJeQVRKVAKuGBVSQ@vqYj24KtMGPpmnwSO7EjsNSU1QQBGwYLNwziOBNKToCI7Fsz9MIXskEjyy@5WWZjhQtJM@TGgemeyQGCCoRPqFjVhxFZEgVbKCX8HgNNSBG5GuHojgxSRVmmAdIiWx7uFdLiaeilllqoPNVQ4TysWOLJ90gHuAqvQx/K0wRCeTixHIgPLZAiEJgPB1t0YChLC@WQA4WpKhnpreYgIMSlLj8JpMx3g0oSqJdBZI7xMmdM7IbUKE/R0cpSXx/tQ96HffFHiUmGk5Q4cNj4oWSZ45heEZrzISC@p9wxlp48jMjQukhiG9EKTeDXiOZi4XQ013JPJhYrxJy4TbggNkhnxYCL@5tiHU4h4DyjoPHWPcCJ4kF64IuOO1zlpGWYg1pM7lrWFxCJdkWE7o8bnaOAE4WeUBcdipXUuyoGJHD6W5ESvSciUqixN7wGhz2kB8UzBGpUiIW8n9RgaO5Y7xhL4QrcjhR7ItqRIgrKPfbqkUIHJT7bdWCA8eK/fZqEZwVHbKW4k/Xi0RJcBagUaIYMdCcUlwGBQHjONR4CooImjTjZ8WYtjKH2phUFXOd0oyqFLJIHA2XTIMeY14w4vaxZHUE5jXC0mhGuYU@zrgw2@GJFyL34RCpJie7BF6a0wc9YaaDFKiMmipeSRJGAInNJ8HEmLnPbTfpxKA0H7DQGBRPRe32krt7E2iDXqWgziqUwelIEfE7c4nPzZ5SFQ2xyrP374TWZYJqNHhyvTZCy9KcFV/pDqoyMaqSuYuVUJLFCzDl7oUpdw9M@Rgm0bBXob8kZ8rDc4DNu1Ccnc3ioMc7GEgJHCBp2xZOYuM4@Eqf3IVzCZStFNnU6dyqLIwQ6cl34Xg8jYPOXe@Fq3HCs6fjrNtH03OnTz1byNlkXZlDUUhVapasLJJFUpvGuwIuUJVobKtdtHpWOBJI3V3S/JwIERlNiXvhIlAqeWpRiCxq/8UF/MvGijXZHjjhiWkY0Jalz2wOGjKCzzDxrWJhhJggS45DRUCSEbeHTgs/Gq1Ony6BB8ovjKbemZMnfMInNulUhKxxiZWoccEQLhJOQW8VyLd5w7M700/NTX/gDkDH6cwlgOD7OI/PJ6WmRHqkmk4Nre/Vl83tz2bzFdfbps5@u38jfzST9RJkHTemQ6N2zCvR@9@GWeQlKIHfQpNvBHVkAZEP5xKJC@26mNxizqjfMj3pPk2dx9DwwcdIi2uuJKVSrG7AkFmcPEQ3QNHxyKZIEtVgrAg@Gw1wvcbnxp3YuHGOzOQVeBoW74wnaE3GJGiOtm/qjjiKSHSYXQ/XL0LYLB6Pjpu7KAXLMYDRvhmb/nzP7/xomyIELZJvYWtlftljraY77TkV2SglQRbXNZVJckzLfRcoOKFWQ1DlaUUlqDu4GLrCNXOhL4Firs6fAruP9nSbQgSVeFGSYsA7hfr2OlpezMzRIGRlWDT3YOU8dSuc5b6HujW5r7r134CT0wUqxdxCexAdbPlOoTY9yKcLb4ODr/tzjm55c7q/nzjwpDUJRgV901svFAp4CM7M7Xa4QIGrxJabT0LncU48P7j60nvTymPU5H12c6@zQxoAFKFxaQLrCS5NjKC/iR2nhfM5Du7K@eBzSH4CT5uRGacVGre/OaXKRyiReWaZvccMYv7es@C6aVAc@ZBBYAnszSA2qqGXcmAmB@xBjw6eqBOapBEyGjeLXQu48FGtXUsPxBWPNM@H1/Go19E2RPm5adtulr11Pbu9JPPdockI@/vxCAUOgqaEvPH4dD1ElpmXlh27IgNBkDbXNjXb7fI7lvD@XD77SXuZPHOAK2kK9mPHZndvPFDkxjsZKiZkOYPZzDC5idt7ujJ0UTItod@Nlh9IBmTfC7qvDxSD@DQNDH2g2EsVuYCiVbxEk1sH43zKLmQZjTmUBIjKz4XhPLsbGpk6n1ztg2s5CmQdgyXcLkdbv6l4KScLwEPmymfjYgd5WOA4BE14BOL9YtxU8NCp3/6Ds9s4c4CbG2mON9wSGztvLJ6PYDIeWxa7HHY60Lz4THwtOGosQEeiMlckKwVkjShYz/x2BPqMku74aX6AHZranEwcI0FIo9TMsvRo2NlKA4bfKY9S0AJF8wN@otnEVzlo1vsjuiclkmc0DYcGFLNyByOcYwRJemhUv71S6vU6Wx5kMqxefwqOXI7Vn9bZM/R4@pQ9g/en@P6oWlpfr3DLuWfqNXg@DTxv2FPAQV0Q3sn2DF4hjK5awqEUFvFyvrqcrSyfV3dqFT/fqD9t5vNdcP3d7//k7/7pn@Tr4uV7fHlKL413IZCmafll43r50U0F3xvPmunlVmN50Ex3K1jLUNy/9nzd1mPbxDTjH@Re3GDnvKEy0GjVajXN0p8@cdfZMHJ6kRMvMYii6/agp1N0Rhhq1XQ9/egRuHaq6R@nVTy5Q/jrof9H8GcqynJaLybW0vJx/WT34CB@T1B4/2gHNU1ccNeFcZrl@BZk6n0qWD3PNZimsWaOvQ/JQ4Pucw6YJJGl0WKUE/OdIDLIHVnfk5UqJczNT8nAiNs9cWu0vt8l86LAQInCyBgMIz1sl7npHOHIgMBD@ArflKrw5obZB3LR1q2aaxQ31pu5VCpFKZN17rlBYo5SG0RXFRsxY1mydOMn6g2gyUDeERuS3GCAEJmRSj00gI5HhjjHwaG7ITHDdF5hOpWOHY3BgCST3yr4ILyKl5G2IXaWYQ9L1EFnPqLt1qgbTO5ruAcEhDegs2tGt/PK/NLZSewywNhFwHjiyfQt8eEpu9E98XRNfIDQmDqJYRohZx6M7qkGVUUeg3dQN2Yr1XtxWw9bC1aWxI571550bbw8kzZN@FcgnYDzqigs2wlORcQUeMyW2cGFT96ieYFFm/ZIMTRxL6xj4OoCqAWOjYfocoUvuDYZNEhoD6jhiHM4OrjnW7EdvlXA7YBTxSvug@uhqRpm6HAnXqFwUY2OiOHxAzmwMgDddcAhkavwHpnZUvVAI29hoPFg1uByoIqYtKAnatqggRZ9xWZwmL8qWpJMbSU02QGtso9DUJwUAaYgpEYnzoJomLD3tvN@3rXRZKVISfJkStwSGSRWmIwlFl4pOb7pV1Z5bvB8WkcfCvYOXN@3hKGKKCaywuG7hD3AepaWeGKitsQv1l4ZhC0qnr@gKpljqOc4D8bPHIHUIZOiFiQA0XgTLQ@5XVzq/2vvWnrbOGLw2foVawm1pa0cSUnRJE0bwLnl0BZIe5MLay2vHQGyJWhXSY1A/73kR3Ieq4lfcFOnyMHGanfnxeGQH7kcThSPi9PVWeSelPVsKlulpPVdk8VLpAPhu5I35bMNkfEg4aA2wWjhKNNdqBoJiqn29YBOvCuZ1/97B70L0MxCjKS/lrVlOXbM4WbnyBPJ1@g4ARXERNE@wjmlFNyJGHNens/qqExfNl3r/lIZxcZIz4t8gojHgLoNynJskJ1s7UTCROltQdgseO0ZCdoXEl2d5j0bDGs1icVyJWVISJzxYps/nDyy7oS9phVM5OPl249nCMqVdd2sEj6WOfGsmvlZuLYFVK5dFHmRYyc/KlBp0aTJwZjP921Qg8RpYxl4KTyMqg8YmJk71OSQUQ3yynQJJNgS3sYv1tNN4rz6f7PdaCpPVpxqlhYfvcV8QDraB5Of0BuXU49uXJXJFfixNKDO4neG/Uur9ZyQvwSpq0YJj4T3jbp@NJqyoesMHwApLS1h2Xg/nMtGURuvL/1XXPpgX3I3fLIMDt0A6Sx7mthBn@6IMidtavVKaobu0H5uLIeEpmBwkek2O0pyqNfijMnDse4szf3kbFKsYTa8SXkbsyILDo0JK0ddyD2k74Xx/gkibeDCOVzXi7f1w2N6@O7Qm9mZu4lj5wkXFASDFSIUvYFe0eUYR1g/kFnAcmBGgkB2qhRVSdetliAPtTDbv1bnbxZ/d4f9o/ZRuz/68WWvDTvZ4bDOtCLLqDMtOaJ6xVZCqbYnaWKNkPtQighfncxOTwlx6OEJVFRbc4@Otdoxe8g/OXFXHUDVtiHEy3Ygy6sDmkTcUFrjerkqzi8KXP62@HNVXL0lJYSfv1/KfP7B9b0jZcSHqOLJO1mjh6cENdobtpM9T9xqiHCZF4R8pjWgQV1KqgQHFxIEKLcIIG268VfxYAMyhOMX34VDz9CbNKkTQSiVxIZPJCfgBCYAb08gO@1Y7hFvqglTIZ@dXOKRGARNAMkPbCdPcFdKCNSfZ6@5TJTSz2dUA@N10ZqU6mdzYtChmVzXD2UhOx8nrvfVRA2bevr@@GI9r2c6sq1h2bi4UD8TUqz5hBEdJmcR5Gx4s194A9TPeIj0yobR2WXYpF0wDq53PKNV6m0ZCCpPBTXCrJbAfjRyY/xwO3rQoKaKZHB/@gP4Y7h5dc3cCLp/baYGJ1jnJG7BdGC8TPPA3JCMg07PZm7Uu5Hxwf0gonA38iXLZBHNm3COeYY5BTyEiZvcL2Gzf81Grtxhkh17KpldqmHUIsO8rY/9w/1seICvBaFVS5yCwtXiwqIt1ZwIjNfgmGdaQbyD/L82WG@w3CL0F5DK9meG2GU3WmgROLSNcQE5HYiBZg5nAWMNwUiIJCBylpoBTejcDpJWsq5PiA0xSuhN6XMTZBticiNNiDeqYkt59h2M2HrUM/TmEBBeJZ46NaGq2s0rNv0YzF49r8GsrzGmDCF75hWox6wJI9yxwY2EKrcJNbofoaRfKTrJkwcjU0yAmEqbVivFvk506IbRcK27XAFbcgmE23VAuFFHAujiu2bQsWZ1NIGG7F8aGM6zw3MSizEWlqiBwt8Tq0cMyKqRG8o54mRLzXpV/kSImNBVi/4I8rKUwv64yANCkHXQci8hEwRTA/R23gjNTZYNOr2WfpkdSChRd/R81EMjt2ipFZ2bcWd4L2KQP8WcbaW5YIUCyJFnx5oq5GbtB133Gbd0NL6kS5oksndKi3jOl0vesnuTl3rQsSOyMqo@62X3dFDDV/JUdBD7eQad1g51QZAGB2xRYyj9vTp4q5KGsbQtM@LO9Yk/xD40R/dj8n8bjSuk5Hcc4ADC0NAB4zOuVSdYEQJCCbFA97@r9onUbsN8shUP1QAXQdqIk02Dj1RVJx1CblagpSvzKQJqB17FpNfUPERZJ1ks68r@3mKOT0fllB3hzktV9QJ/sLodBvuWLZq7JSlRXJWRuAqHs7eXad/gsm5gjKShHxFK@hER4@hShHOTdUkI8U0QXlUKLROH@pZJ/4O8oG/41bmXBiIsXj0O8R6agaf7@tJRPk0dFL2OPjyg80UjlQBoIgfQWZJH35vWXQnapOcNTAqH3tfDpXeaiduyqkuUnuZF0cXPR6KLQ91zVQ3Y28DaR/LxS0YfpJDx@ifLwzRLO6J/4aagf8KgfG5XUbt0YSTtq1oiR3s@yKOqn1Q11Ncr//mR7TjRScXpKanjNe/Gv6qpCt6Ij9PnAjpLoQomxd0Uphnp0ryKQjIxuStNy0xLe7ssg2EWmL@WfwyUOtOETTtUHcKLkLOFP10tppIBjIMA2TmAuFLYtSMxi9ggkoJj/qmJVHbOJB/5ma5kGUGWH2uzOgbtDwYhGOvNqqhvBbH8JznZ3Z5dcjZYPmugwYfVkxYfmnlXSHYbXJbfGpd1cvi0cw/P8s6SsMWze9bxZXGad9BSPW3X8zYvVDjwYXIQiWmC5lf90JmvUiv85HZ/2PcNvjxWxZA/eviSO/JPYxCTexAzTYIY/4KWmrLjDeXc@xAPtGwvYSHnCnukvUXcHq0ba2@RbK8qOcNw5t/Twgs0y7cTzdYfF1rCMao2CP9jsiGWtbKmJ21d25Osu72gZb69Gn72TQ3/n9XwPw)

### Explanation

The exact language used is text mode of 1L_a105 standard, interpreter is [here](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/1l/impl/1l_a_mmi.c).
In this dialect first character in the file is used as space in pre-standard 1L_a, everything else is a wall.

First two examples below are in pre-standard 1L_a, so they can be executed in [yoob](http://catseye.tc/ix/yoob) too.
To run this code in Graue interpreter newline must be added at the end.

It is very hard to program in 1L_a, so I used automatic search. The idea is to split program in cells, each cell prints one bit. 
One to four additional asterisks inside cell are enough to make cell produce needed value, so the cell can be found by iterating over all possible cells with 4 or less asterisks.
First cells with width 4 are tried, then with width 5, etc.

```
 *                         ******* ******* ***** ******** ******* **** ****** *******    ******* ******* ******* ****** ****** ******* **** ****    ******* ******* ******* ****** ****** ******* **** ****    *
 *                         **    * *     * *         *  * **    * *  * **        *  *    **    * **    * **         * * *    * **         * ** *    **    * **    * **         * * *    * **         * ** *    *
 *             *********   *     * *         *** * *    * *     * ** * **   * **    *    *     * *    ** *   * * *    * * ** * *     * ** * *  *    *     * *    ** *   * * *    * * ** * *     * ** * *  *    *
 *             *                 * ** *  * *   * *      * *          * *    * *     *    *         *       *   * ***  * *        *   * *       *    *         *       *   * ***  * *        *   * *       *    *
 *              * ******   *            ** *   * *  *       **  * *      *  * * *          **  * *     * *    ** **       *  * *    ** *  * *         **  * *     * *    ** **       *  * *    ** *  * *       *
 *              * *        ******* ******* ***** ******** ******* **** ****** *******    ******* ******* ******* ****** ****** ******* **** ****    ******* ******* ******* ****** ****** ******* **** ****    *
 *              * *           0       0      1       1       0      0     0      1          0       0       1       1      0      1      1    1                                 same                       
 **************** *        
                  *        \---------------------------- 1 -------------------------/    \---------------------------- 7 ----------------------/    \---------------------------- 7 ----------------------/
*******************
```

Note that y position of IP, tape location and tape contents are exactly the same before and after printing first 7, which makes it possible to just 
reuse the code to print second 7. This is a pure coincidence, I didn't do anything special for it to happen.

Version with merged edges between cells:

```
 *                       **************************************************************************************************************************** *
 *                       **    *     *       *  **    *  **      *  **    **    **       * *    **       ** **    **    **       * *    **       ** * *
 *             ********* *     *       *** *    *     ** **   **    *     *    **   * *    * ** *     ** *  *     *    **   * *    * ** *     ** *  * *
 *             *               ** *  *   *      *        *    *     *       *     *   ***  *      *   *     *       *     *   ***  *      *   *     * *
 *              * ****** *          **   *  *     **  *    *  * *     **  *     *    ***     *  *    **  *    **  *     *    ***     *  *    **  *    *
 *              * *      ******************************************************************************************************************************
 *              * *
 **************** *
                  *
*******************
```

Version for polyglot is obtained by replacing all space chars that IP visits by `#`:

```
#                                                                                                                                                    # 
#                               ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    # 
#                         ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    # 
#               ###############    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### # 
#                #        ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## #### 
#                #                                                                                                                                     
#                #                                                                                                                                     
#                #                                                                                                                                     
##################
```

The most natural place for 1L_a code is before line 19, because IP would encounter non-`#` character naturally and turn left (east). However, placing
code there would require to return IP to the left edge of the program to exit which cannot be done because memory pointer would go below zero. So
I exit through the top instead which requires to place 1L_a code as close to the top as possible.

There must be room before `#####` line for Simula and Lily, so 1L_a IP first goes to line 9. Simula (`#comment`) must be before
`#####` line because it requires `#` of preprocessor directives to be in the first column. Space in first column on line 10 is used to turn 1L_a IP. Lily (`#[#[`) must be before
`#####` line because `###` is a special comment which must be followed by valid Lily code.

This answer has two sets of changes:

- to create `#####` line and fix broken languages
- to add 1L_a main code and fix broken languages on lines 1-2

#### `#####` line

Moved two lines added for Zephyr up. Destroyed 3 occurrences of `-#` in INTERCAL code. Swapped `` #`<` `` and `#[#[`. 
Fixed bf with additional `]]` and `\[\[` on lines 7/17.

Moved bf derivatives line to catch Wierd, note that zkl's `#<<<#` cannot start on second column, so it stays where it was.
Line 9 cannot catch Wierd IP because there is a space in the first column on line 10.
Removed `>>` in the beginning of bf derivatives code, angle brackets do not need to be balanced there now. 
First `x` on line 10 is for 1L_AOI, second `x` is for MarioLANG.

Moved `8=,` to line 4, added `'=>` before main cockfuck code.

#### 1L_a main code

First `#` in `##*/` on line 1 is for Turtlèd. A bunch of `2`s are for Pyth, `7` before them is for l33t.

To fix Prelude what was moved to line 6 and `(` was moved left on line 2. It broke Deadfish~ (`iiipsddpsdoh`), so it moved left too.
`??` on line 2 is for Brian & Chuck. `a` in `a5` is for Del|m|t, `a` after MiLambda is for Beatnik.

Interpreter has a bug which requires to have non-`#` characters below main code (line 6 cannot be shorter than line 5), so what code on line 6 is padded with spaces.

Didn't move l33t to line 1 because it breaks 05AB1E. Didn't move Shove (`1P''53'S^'`) into 1L_a because it breaks MiLambda.

#### Others

Cubix is enclosed in `[]` for Agony.
Haskell: moved MagicHash code to one line.

Answer (score 7):

## 179. [ORK](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ORK), 9911 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111x            -xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO 8=,_      x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps    # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._       #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]      #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqTqTqTTcTcTc                            #
############################################################################                                         p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>x._++++._+++._^<][4O6O@]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                        _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyYyY
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"' 
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=96los*81''ca
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss_ baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8SDBB15VKD662F1V5JCsqukBUaxEIgFkEchEZwIkUCy27Z5kc/s4k@5m587mdnXbM6uTac10H9ZOktmd7ZrJTPf1bH9E78c1meYfjNw9Il94kKyZXTuBBDIywsPDw8PDw@Pd0r3eb36TwA87dvrTbt8ZsZHpjVjbta5MV2PPpuypbnnFwrokIVTd7Y4Hpj3ySlKC5RmzbMNqwzsbOZembX00XfAvMDZ0na6rD9iop4@Y6Rn60PSYMx4NxyPmdBZHW2dsf@B8sDIYc2DZXQAbme7QNUcUvsHYa7uvD1ptfSakOJPg0IVwj@2Z/U@DTyNmOIOBbrc9gNxk7KXjeibCG6bnORh9i7HJvmnMIN0GUN21nBf1V1/OBO0w9iWQqA/75oTpLW/k6sbIcmzkSY6dvnp9ejwTI59nb84ODmZ9C@zrjGOzg7FxORu0zl67nt7XZ/FvsPp45ByOZv2LrN41bZ0VtB2tMBu4yZ65ejwKFeex67THBrJ61DOBAiyejtU3PckA8BobCqHQ0MESzDX1NgcDrKfOwIxS7THbNNvMG5qG1bEMQsTMyci0PUjQ05gFuby2@n3WNvsQIcRupJnnsLEX8Wr19Z5maFLHcRmmwgaXfWYxYzhkPIj1LSDpILfNTBQa9hHC@z2PTYYD5lkDCB4ZTqdjmuyjOewxqe1IDD7GcCZTwduqCTC26TPGHELhI2MclBXgks@fa1cfDiG3ggMjawCibY2SHjN1z8LKA1E8024TT4dBtXKYbkfZxa4sKFzI@Ngl3J7pYsFohJf1TNcElHog2Mq1a42Al8iLOjs2dZeduaapxqtYLElIzMEURpgRjYq0UknuHx0koWh5DE0fQlG662c/@krSmVZlqxdl@FZluSztv9pjN6vn6OY1Cop/6Cq6yqrfMS97fm7Cd5JvZbvurQRYJeBKn2Wd4SirZ4ZAYGYEBGZ1dKIrc1XQhv1IwqwyUxYRgeNQbSgNdmizN2nKmTF2XdQaIVP1S8h037G7wE/IrDu2kR8228xBERgOVPo0M6@Aa1DLqIyca@LwWc@CQvOwSCKVgus@YihoPxBiwVE/Xc/pjwkOYnojlGTgCkRFjIcd9oZ1dKuPUSAcUXGqXdMb90cYZ2y3seRBt5ltjflkGE4bgQbOFSSnA1LyAMEfRGolEQXAUBAOZRWDfvgXf9budgFP3TActy3E9Q1rOwZpaZ2IBdXHUGAdW@8TWQCXxtR5dEjgSu9bbX2EydtTkQQRQaleO@N@mzmQoHttQR3t6VdQr6FqGSOTCzlX7Gk20C@5LrG45ELGB3oLCpYSoLQp2xn2dBdKyTClBMlMZjAedbZZZrjPkl72nfKkpDxZOTeBOFVT11az2W4ZBE5bIy94S94lOW/qMd3njXTPsdrScDrqOXaBZQwmG1VnaNpKMoYjmU66raSqoY5T1LJVNbSOZbeVZAVksQYJJ9WyUTUaVqlZnokeTRLQXCMarK6mYqiyBCqHKsVVdqBbtjacsjcZ4YqEOd4FshyDtYg3MmbW74p7JKhhQ7l0UEBAD2le3zSHSk7Lq6gmEG5hvjFgUU5ncIgMl6xmKplIpqJZJwyQ01hGsbKeWQ6qrf6wh20aMMX2htAOuCi7hg7S42FzMALrIs1aJNfUhoBmIZ14bSZdk7VAkfpyRFWSVzmMn0FFKTCEVShek812pCKDEoC6PPLmtHHfuYYEiSZsZEB12Jio3oWigcg8I3WeEZ4S@cSzdGmDQkFsLZNtZ1oWVAKsbqDThcxH8gbg6wUOA9h4JYnonoE@BSwGb1TDCsOsDtSlAagHd8oME3UOKB@TNyiYyJjqnwf2FFpWuUyhWIzXsbkqNnKz9cxPQEl/zN5ZkzDz9ZjJAC1Px7xmfd3ujvUumnQ2RNENwxyOhKKCnHgjUEWz7Q15ZkTjqXk9afXpbNrUiPiGRZgGKnleeqIp1FG7CKMu0wdlynRhlrK25YJa6k9nUweAq5nE5fcIEiPgvbyEBN8CACEzJ6YxHoFWAwG@7llGD2QWqbO5XuSN0Gzy4BVNHTR7phMkjcTka48LkpYNvJCMpSgyWKLzeKBxRVS1mAcVftTjbsy6N1iA2AlIhIYg4qtldQ1k7x6cA8d2FiAFRgZoESQewssBLLFTNCeh4fLNLqqsgY0ZFBGUGWgNqPkgf73RaOiVoJ2wRr1xSwNJyZ6508PRkY3Ckh25U2vkcHer77RALXtQP7N@Cllj3LImMxkiv6AMP3jSFRhgHY9VoeX@dgxSpyQ7HihM8t9F4EiQTIqbUPBfGQAJSANGKR2PVPEBKJXTqW0oskZVSYNKJ6eZjBVXVsGBsQK@7DoD1ELsLRkGaOmBiW/ZHdBWQueTytcXNnWB7ie7LpnUPjiWrdwkV1ZWkqVkDTT7ysoTcFXQ9QRdKXA9IVeGXAinoYtipMmFoQ2KgX7N5G3DxzxRm1hsE2yVPlpDRW@USuvNtN7Ii2cBnyqoOtBsAJ3BB@BJqtUqOlVVrl1DRrVWJ577XdTOp4ZrDQUTvtKvdP4uuLBObLAGQ8dFA7aMjezdPBlUXWgFwWg1eoqbPG/kzpvnN@ft1PltMo2x1bJebUGmID1loHVdZwzNpdrYKGXyTVVtrEMj2aomc8k1RdnO9CEhXVW/2FZTOue2kjRBayvn50lgquBPw@i5hG@SLqhqwCqgAxtmsAmVpHazDem31KaaSkJcNZmGLkY1mQTOGMgEjzKNkkkMOgAB3D19EetVDi5BPTLD66MtkXG5OQGv2TXu2aZHYDKV2CGZnDa0l0ACNJftoGtjO3bGHpMBTNapE02IenMIQX7YeKBitGIwiLhjTcDCh4o79S0ZbIDRmNmF/qLTN7W3ZFvIDCSfYX3VFpozx7xd0AwvLEQwXMA57OsG1Mw4unOZnQNCENRsdnGIWp5DPGvrULfkvjxCy2DoNvKvbZHZPba8HrIXTCPsC7gd4Cra3NC4m8S1Q2ZAo90FTpsTa8SNcBCEU4zyXPcUFc2@Ojeb0FrDJh@J8rvw1B47BnRYTGj6MZT3/ti@fWW5jo1M1vYBNUhsGctgBvki9oIY1euHhb3l/F2EHDg2552P8DaKdZa5hmewrO30na7D1gAARVPTuGAf2gaQAEbbCPqH0NP/SAyqdx3oucRl0MT22kMjL7@5HpjPOkJmCV77AMqCLc50CLAkz6eHP9kHFZ8v5nJAv/@Wo0@QyQiW2Tyip8FCADG@1ke5wZL8iTnsTd2YOHmO6AaCPDkmr5i8Yw6d/CFQJWr4R4oareTcB@q5H9T2XYvyvk8mDo5FRLsJsdyDNQf1VGSHVxvIYWLGG319VsSQzhV4WL4HoPzOemNTMo2ew@RzMBEKNZZtm1dZVDgytMU9sHUzkJTpkjUVRBPjfdLIGYNZ1jb71sAaHdJoVd9G2yNsV/3QXahgIYJjyxxJosMQmiM4ohQ2FXaXw@9PsEXxJJOe7NXR3v7Fcf3seVXOjj0327daIMFt82IAlmPf9GQ2@0mwExOQifgfL/snjjOq8uK67LN7PwmM40d/sXfx4vDZSf3kG04EofGswbivIyml1RkAjH5KwX6tigzjdVxnEJjUniiI1XVkvRkboMX@pQjdwNCxGJ6N@G@i/wCHXDVD6hoGyzj8NfAUgFsIiMOwmjEcSt1UCiFpWDbwFJDbhBKHZjW35XvuoGcwKBvptUTRLQpfHklgvsnnbhG5Z4@9YSRnN/k8@V@NOh1sdgPvAnlfZlDU@6H3OnnzQd1YUj5b5oIWAgf4NggfHwxeiG8uaCFwgK/I8eEg8mJ0MyGLQANkm4QMB50X4poJWADIxfIMFOELB5qvF5ZHEwdROZUCO@lckn1jL2bTyWFIIRx0YZmrxaNFchQR1SAQ8ksH@xih6yKn5YuIJUAxuOzPx@xAS08/MdA5ouZDeM0dtDr0swCgJAYiQEnhuDpy5SscTMWxEgfsLvOawKhLRciAW5atZ0/ogZ2rRfTEu4kxYlpmZwwmSRZsXnTfA5bZ2SbITqtlLQMFviDp/nMBmDtuLWIbdPF6cyMJLMb40dgd9c22eP6X32tDAcwXT0@fkhkWOC6AbyQbnaWlJaLiC/0sLlmC@TDuWzqxgVz3oTR0HLzV@4FjMWpsT1gm09PdAVo7onBBOPEHVNAdcsYpd83@uG36z8WJEIvj4xU8tm0NKEfwRHOdul9Los@MtvD4ZPD2Hb1NWLhZaplhafNyMSfcQIvYPaDlH0CnPyjCwlkI6P2PxvwXJx7uK1driN/FXCnFhSxX1Ft5M@t4essy75ADV78ct53M8LJLmUbSNpdJO69E2IfPdPr6JXdeoHMxA3gWXavbNV3/uQzsugeWFpmI2Wt63CEqfjvHyHLR78Lp9vnvMhB/mjdwLOeT1aefzxFIEhEDag2yFucWMxE2WTOM7eutKZrKvc@XLEyQDAhQPFUjlcqtYxMWDCWHs5jD4fL42O5R/J2dxbH5rCYhEPOW99RmaJGsgd7PFNoR51Ll7I8Nha4FoNQfyhh93QMhGQk2m1dQLPRzl@BiI2OguISuO8Q2JMefKVg26BzGGVqG07e8Ia9J4mWZlpwdrgvR4LQx/YRR8W2ev23o9mADnglciyu6Y4xw4HeJHD1AcfExVxzVjgiG5izjneFc43ep6dBzrkz@u7gx@7iQqgeooEyfJMMyFkRvG/eJK04d0s9iLl4upGpk9Bf6l9hLx3F7pu2xgpbzB6lw3kbv9/kg8Nnh0XKZ9qy@40EHCH/v4gV0dDyP/y6W5ijbLN3O0FBc1L04miBqyDQxcrGkMPV@1@lvbnezOvwsLfGx20HNLp4P1WiBRsrn79VIgeHj2HnxXKrKL@H/PmGg4T4Xx/Ujzjva0UXqS4wHL88gdA9wsm5x5g5y2xRTy/Le6LICcI3etT71n79Fa7GMu35rMZyS2Qx2HUbY2QbHyOWm9G@T2sbdqbUfppPm0G7dl4lI4V72TdDQ9DtXpKyQy39mjHwu93AN1emPzbG5UGMctT6YuMzqDl3xcKJyIhurYtwmC8zDUZsA6qPoFD6Iamy/8e1OBaP3Lajk91ovC/XdEGztIfajj8FxjI75iF17PIwVboR3J2P75G7O9YZ@zXbaMSIx5HM10vb9NlLMHPdM@i4z3fcHDnR9nQHYDPYDyl8gpaEu/htDTD4h5g8WjiG6d@ItsWACEOxVsD@gVK1LL4MDkQ9TPIVlfXYC3tmBXpltjqb4u4zbixRpy3H6n1M6oE/bFpplYGziUrz7SmnO1hFzwSwcnfBwpKPVWTYuwdsa0YEE7mFneWlBH0OWRtQ4PKSU58Yy72i1IiOb9/UjocWmwR/PNXz3MnpPsHLntW1t606CuTnqtMy@zh@TzY278O1o6w8xiYa@nUsj4Th6zsfLwwmHxIwKGk6BWVY74xk9c2DS6x1Gvt7@MPb8x1KgiYPfBcFalkZ/l8QbWlDnbfyNjc1HrKKRY5tedqS7XRO7J32cNBK@y/SsP6i8kLmHA71rHtwrXOHoAy4UoknZiHPxOESJz90bEO0eTcJ7fo59aU49/7nYPp4aUJ7jwZ3YFtVzAwc5763YWnbhWPo9Zp/dc3p2z@y5VDmCt2XVAyRyxNdY35UJoL@ne5e4Mop0Utit63lR7vadfv8h3EWdyDWk4ywef93HNc1tiPpZeKd6CwLE496hOmi6iUnUhi@rOz1zDC2U54ycoZmht2WgfRzU4b@Lh5QPj5Iee2uZbpvPCuMInz6yWn2TXVtAwgcvOhW5eMCo1Xd0XHx3hxEPnPGfDxmCMhz33nGQru6MhkN6XAz7Y49@aCg301k8RlliB0TpQ4TBGvEJeS6yZtdpGT3rPpJapj6yrcusqP7idbGYx5Ux5dximT301voW8MqdaigE1Wj4KT4OF1d864XYInGnQbI7dt3p/cohPtUaDKvyyQB0LBuAEbNiC4Kp6cdVJ/7qijtmJMQk2lKJImMaDeeMmQPrJL90OCi2QkawoL@@PrqHS4ZjXN5rTywdoBTzr8gqw4rMIYP/7CjG3WQ8F/oNeofK83HXU@8X3F4b7Cr8WSgk9S4XEJww8vrOdWRAGaq@bovHwriFF/enTrMexTsnQEos/@KifnR4PzKjbw09/ssyncJCU2F@7nQeaqovGUs6BSHvPLxjMHBcXCkMlkTGcE3PwAFuVMJcOXLNYztdUMaZPguBfdiF9M/P1S4yUeINXebHr8yujguPXli4Bqnvzbd9gHl22vYhiH801j3rR2NnZC7EOTt9@xCUL/WuZTyPFYGP0OeuWKXCHzFtiV7zBXHdszxasOk7lhkSIGl368PZEfdg85A/dnDy9V3x@WT1CW0@CZYpe2mxOAf8LFfskfA0fyNSghYy0aJlfxErS@BS6jEqjZHjaozgFEVPpVRV4pFw/LVrA5gPRVtBcJk432Xisb7ljQjW6rBGg63eTEq5Uv6WVZlcklmzybHihxYt70@GtI/jhEdvrOrN6moyk0muJs/tEsslA3Cz75mLwfUYbMeiB6c3ZAGzdb5cDd1@jst8GbzXoy0m0NC2ocF@Df08UtqOyxdz850CZzih@5//si123oBV77GBBdUeGILbzpyB2XOun/B0Rer14VDHnTuIA4Skz9eRZ3brzLvGlp1vuHGu2euDs22xjF/scYOXY2yCIlTwwsUuJq7hG/HC49QE67FEwkEsP1OG0x8PbLCl2qOep4HKoeV5YzdcZwMuBLNHLhqU7TQ7ZG0Tp81o1SX1ofqOc0nrn5GS//yXfPMCrb0Ua@L85GnTUiRFXGKZpx0DhuGMgWofyUfTdQSIgkyGCj3GEQoQbpP7q7gikXZVgERm/D0FlAzfWLBbP2WZfZbE7Xu4VLlsdZTV@smXbxq5ZvU7Nsia/@X3suqNYJz8RWZn05PTzAcp36JgRYOLEByGJpm8OpF5gsHCVEs03Ne8PIBFOhcyXJvqy5jjDEWtoX1htA0qkEaxF1VBN5Wzv7lgQFvKSGDNa9pcQAvCbFR0uFfL9qCCwatKqHmtq64qY96JzpyOWBESxA0aOrj4JjRaqokL5THK6oR9Yj0UsoyBywfhjTOyj3szBtVn/jqK9ehql@ye2RrTFO9VQSusVyk7qxfVSo1crtl2cI9U4935pJDLnE@29ptZz2fq@fnki1zhx8B1B@z71cdZrHn7r/ZuVrVa7tMnT58yWb5NlvnyHVATqzfHh8f7p2f1s9enUAq3vvo5cNyBHuoalCJaENhz@rT7DPjiWqb3GfoneANwRWGrOqvgHlpVlaJr3QhU8FrOyKvcGVFNsdj3RF8U3zMj4fMAQqd1LOZLVLhGGtoDLEyQOmQfcmE8xM10TCARG4JI3CxU9liTAg7haqkFSpV4JrMqcC0DXHsgz9jyXD/hfg9h3b1Y7ubfk4UgyLogvUYQzrO4kAW3/yD5HkKL@bvnm2O5O98Ec0e@ATTw9eMc1A9fvD7Zj0cDYaMnqd/qTlGs9uRaGqsc74j7O6BoYbyIiCMRVZnJFIG/ilZtjHtjWubo2oRsCS1pDHhkklCiX5ZCwQTOVHG7ebPMeaEoRAEaI2XM1sxi1I41iZDoN9YRdDc8i4E2OJAD1D7hmiwwJ2gzuIYfPxuIVbDLr4PHpM2F4k56UTso7dc4zBo21mOP17klbVbQ/HgM/iPNk@8qNNmEiXYt32QZVoBv3wTLvhfAqmXeWLFVzgh5ldMuB/TiVmSgqf1Bp54ALcUR622hue7rQ9z3KKBfgfVdYt@OHVrc7yuTwNC4dtxLXDOAe@6paA0dc0ObBuwR7mH0GzDCd3hwWkUzjdtopOijMje2scUCoMge@P0JGPggbB1S@nw3LWe5IzZu@m0mjRB5YqNWYC547MryaAQJC6GDxk4fNCXmRmQcCoNv62D1vgfGSRvacTBVRtjmgpWi0XpSvqg0YzM5ATKpBbZjmskSwnrV@Y180KZeG9C@vueRVwmOMHvSgh3H52b2h3/xZ3yX8fkI3H8o3JPcM3j7Y/HWAfc/90PyeXj7l8FbAd5@xt/eZZGj81sreW4CJiID3xweM48GuZBFA30SyT1WXCxKyx5DsQ6A11fEOgTn2Qo5E@JRGm@A81BcwHY0H9BioPRMt6ngxrhSNovWNc5MaLTy0ZzwES7aJ/ftGPeHg5GT3SxubuSzQGTmykdIe126uNSOI1TVEqga6coaVt@3DFapVJjsGXrfrG6WOcuzq/q7dfl9QOgqwErcEG8wiANRwhgQVhPRlFU9lVcxKrYPyXwSVUXb4SUI1pZCDgBR0dv2NwuAOecIVoF42OZkRBbJ1O9ggB60afm5yU8J8BFlABHHjbuYZ6U8XDyHa40jcq9Fi0F@i2CnCFaSFwlZ4x07H53bTbGbnYHA/HKByNng/qMFW9wD6anP761WZndGY27Y01PbwUWWB0AtUwrZwno2v6lG6pQsUAG9WIM@AUqoM1AHDdP64Ay9@u7@4VdHx6dze4QJMjkLlmTJWiV1ntHSjWbgSM5Ivc/UZwfZ05fPDnxWRqkK5ygRIpyonCVzUWqzlC5J/S1ftTifNgXMJZTPPRQxzQhkDmgufx57GJqNAO7yVVVzqSrqzW2jWamd24m55D8tOjchoa2hcIHr3KNTE5Jsgc459NdinuHZO57mL9ovyOGpIMFCff4eei/f5Ruc5BNu9fVXfUq0hyfYwiNpS9aDQt61LE@K9rlywnx6Qdf4pOaR1DBBQ5qbZ45Sw0Re5g8dEjsWAiYd8TEaOr5At6Fb7loGh/ZIQfORHNpzD334w0hrbPRobQn1PKfUkwdVEYzuti0aJ9Ndf/NIEHJqDqzMmU8PKo5w667Ys9qDvPWtVlmvNiYs2PJw1w5WzRv2rZGC22knGo6QQG4UFTOQr@B@1Ila2WmKrb/M36Gbok2@x2Pg17EzZOHo1J7pu07ARGF7Y0BuYP/mq/EA4Dr0ODGxlTDBaMlAZOBj0ieigdtaRR60QbsIqWs9c9K2utDSKGoaVNIX@Xy4PVjH/a12EvQwZ9WXuPguypjP2tIc4Zje0DXLbpsTBTeflZrIHfBPXr@9SqrynAzQvmqxzbg9u8HaVxb6SNTacHPyjELY2QkUQbzu7OxoPU/CLSlgDEOKpyP3BTihDVU6A33IlDHtUPeYxuhVOVfstDdyVZapYXt2zWyWSlGnGh4UALYygnbIZdFOQgUPdFGyVShn9PXsNj4@WkPWyGtaE9yUiMpWcUBtF8wNHIpSJegbQZQSoYUGGP5KSBEYnW2kiD9XKVmJ9pgC1MJgqsjdHlVA4AXlmtUehxv6IjWQc3VnpyRKI64OdxiIRWWBxgC0C9Scb5sCf8WmAuAaKjGA2nXNtgUK5enXpm1DfVVAZgZQO5k@BiFz1bR/6Fk6PKiGUkhwEp@LXQpAaPwAm/3kTd8Be2Y1W6axmfIttPvvz7Hh74imf5r9b7NatnyjrPar0ywYY2pNWe1V86n1tVRq1V5TVm00Rx4/xiGd21Wwdi406BhNACiz2lfLIM9gHVVX7fKqXlFW29XCGsWAV@ia3UCE77ysdrOq32ZXH4M1kQYfl9dOZdWjveU5TcvfAn1YQ1azaZCZG9xjTUeZYfKrViqFNGirF0jAd9nz0xS1K@enWRo9KgsjN9sd@GokbqsEJTF3BBtnoPAuBRq9iBpdrES58IHD42vWF4XdaV1/jev2GE0xmp4Xla94yMMVi1BoqJyEklH45n5g4EQBJuJrWldVUCa/@U0iv8mY/GRzXXFST4q5cipZzJeTCZZ4CmZqdk125ZvzvcwVMzPJRkcvat82jy@Pj3@snitshyUTu0dyfkN@x3YK7GGfLVZY8mG/yyeRWMtKiexa7tNWNvv@/XswyFmjptW0ptrIJJsNJUy/trW1lt7cXks/TV6EvqpSKKinICrs3LKsodduw9fp0ZmDSoJ/njyhlKDLCf@M@4nUhcN/QRDhm/hcOL2YYOdbur6W2ig8tctA2w5@1lkenPi7Dd88KxbZPn7@9v/421/87c/p7xf0/WudXbKP8LnsMPwn98d2xK2ju9X5iNv2we6ukk4YJpPF9eTpu6SUqBmJj4l8Pp@Y0t8FuvP5SZTfmcmCTxiczecL52EuI0zADAfejPuwqF/AjYDXTPAo8blwUmKNrW@uPAVZMKHxwU@p9DSSi6y8tS07Dnn1IJdF5iRY@4htV9NCNCYZ/Ez8DIj0WZinMCR8Y1GvBPOjsRDmc@GkhH@EVqahd5psVMc/dtbCv5MR/r25zLy5fHN5YuDfs0v8e9nCv@NT/Bt6@CfwJ8LsCGkO3gL5nvXzOR68ML8asM@BkxLfVau8LJgok/nPogBNu/BdF8FgHnsCnxX4o3/4BK/4u0I@wptA5j8rv4PSkRKNRKP6u32aTZEXKVGpVBI/6tGfi3/PbfxrfYt/Lz7i37dn@Hdm4N@d2lBK/AN@HsyPocQSmWYqc3vb0N5NUuWy@Af7ohy84Ye7oESbt5lM5V0tlWpQyTZqoogrmWZtwgucfrWLd5VmY@No8@gp4E9VGpWKdlGrTWqZ5rtaA0viBn8M7xYfBVnOrp2vobM6qZxw1Hs@blSmDP/E5wVPr3H8or67f5YuVDIsUTio76YLp6@fJfL4WgzfKXgd30/263tHryHC8Yv9@un@l4dv9l8fg7/XvKg9fZrSQG88BeJrzYaUmHyRqqWqo9Ho4icXaxqalzvcytyJEDL7uVjgEu9SYq82eZ3NVID2Fxc7mNMTSjEDbGl@Yhz1eeO8Mf0G/6TE@8p7JfUk9STXz13l8pf5y5fOUfh/dDSBAGuS@@C4uV6ul2@Dwmc583VumptOcgPnKN8Gpwl/uQE4rVxnkuvm7Jydz08nMVTL/wdHzujlkQPYHIg5muRGiDjXgWf36Ogl4OtA2h/gz8rlchMgcpK7gv9cn9qf/LuLHORdxYNL4C2XOz@XGkx@b0Jzr@WTWi6pbSaTVrO4Ofz2/Oa2sPltgzpIxZ1mg06pacosnbw4bySb5UTWOz/PcutILmzIZQK4vb242Kuf1S8usliBJpXV1NNU5il8qrVURTyeJNq18pPzUgYF0xfRRLby5Ly2nkH3ZgqKoQB@lWzqMz8hSnjWVs6lpHL99u1b/L69vrrmLnJwv/O3QSj@vM2CF3ehF3wQNLsoftwxmRc@RWkUmze3YCWeJ8tJYUcqjI6EkvPnk0KHFWTsqys7Kpjq@XXsEG4WmVqrbRbBY3NbzSg57MvzKOfycDg8lzUavdRo20e1WnddfYojFsoGIFF2itXquay7F@dyo9DEuMXMziZz3MzOuiqr6rt8pQJpYBIFFbzl5ER23CS7uY3@KTe3FYU@Kv6pKnqqIDj0rKkKAKhFeJvcKKyiVBT0Ay@Md3NbQyfB3YCroahN9faW@yk35VtFrXC0NRU4x8BO/0f6Byvk/z//L18zD4z92wR2QG22UVSV1tRUNzaV7dSO@KuuAGcVeT25jj2LpJ5sNJ6ura9tbTSeNNfYGn7ZmlI5rzUnCz9qMgEV2q@A1XwCSxcVm1Y@kfMFOcmwTpYNcRBW3@my9Z0yniDJIJ4MH3RJSQaFWqsEYhwI9EStoQwwKlWmNpl6ewOiTWHQTVXEzNr5@SSXU1m5VV29Sei3ZSRKZreygPQrB6FWkmVa2SLfyKu628g35Vt59aZ1i335tbxK3bjiRrm8tsHdq4qS39ks7BQKW5ub2/mtbbCSN3O5LMvntwsb2@vFnY2Nze3iJug2VS1Tgmv5NYEnB3iEc7tcNj3dKKPOKieADkVJqgzYnjiXqi2zC8kDX4bR6pwqFosr2QI8Jl9s7hcmbOXTGn4aa1A824Xt1Fqq@bSxtrODpdXEkE8rUhnn2vhSFDkjcx3Atnco3QRNV9OnUpMag0mnSeeWVDON/GaxmUFj78OkswZk5LfWE2sc2lw9JuW2trcGv3n431/BIxGZNKRVMls51sb5RZc5nc4KePZ0j7VwKtgz@33/1LVrx@23r622uSJ5JnwGx7o5Ns3r8fjaDD67lqd/@KAP6TPp/PDLn/7wy//@h1/97Idf/fSHX/3i19//4qfw/Uv4/ow/f/bvd4r4@@vv/@X/8sOf/wo8/xq@/wm@//HX3/@b3@Nfev8b@P5fEb@/Ed8IHP9KgOuPf/39z//i19//8z@F778V3z@d/f7wr/8D//@/xR86f/XDv/4b/BEvP/0ZcOnv/@qX@P/zv/r7//RL/P9f/@e//6t/9fd//O/I8Wfc8f/823/Pf//u93/6d//0T/7u979f8vvTO3@/f4D/9/8IPg@n8yF4HpKvz/X5/rei53fhRpgKyABI2h/98G/@AGT1X/O3fwZv8B8E/WHwEgvhL38YvgCG/2lBpD/69fd/8hfB2x/EAWNhgOQPIezPY2F/@MMvf@@Hv/jvfvjln/3wyz9GPZTZ2EnX05n8PQM4AFh8ABwCbj4EDgA5yApbkQr0xB/hyVbINVmTiuvYD83wT4p7flpFE5Odf5KK8J76lMXz8lj2kwg9x221eQhd36DQHJjKOQwt4qsfGiEFx42ePI0Z85yQtU9PGQBD5AgwAT7hhAr/1KeYMseYFL4SEA7fMLGVIH6se1t5/75aQ4CnEAxNJLWSFfzFF/B5VmWMeqXwqG2zqpRm21U8HwsBq/BO4eikd8CFt09UpT32DHvz6L0HHMLWdjJhE@k9e4/Uon@Ng7KaBOHfgcczjoawIarvJPBKcZ89eH4n4CcS4cN/YaaiG79@APykGPeD1xQiSflsYimJQzAxPDWZs3VpJALhMN4E/1mISOBJScCIVDraEwuSSIVeUvCamksloGcmLBWGMUozFUeVYnMI7wqMeUuzEdlCLIKCpaEz2fRDF6TohybmowRBUQalUnGGYcx4plJSChdJr4lE11JrOHbO1j73I2iiBBay445PlN9rYc6jeEPqQ6xEL4@QItgwbcKocNuKZuBYfnMjQKxKCp2qylQa1DCHYMpJL73uM2ei5NKynM5vLh40UHEIBGC/cUql6nf5jS0JnvQ@xgNexVGjINt4a4dWgQ/QIdVuMuisoBOMtU2pVhOziywv1U73zyDC2RHLF3Iaa@SaNxtbhY3iRrGwvrlZ3CrkNzZ3NjaL2@u5fG4zVywU8mDF7mzvbN1KtR@zicaOj3@UAfckk8kWKIlqvrhVnlYhInlJNbIbuXU5vcl4YFkiWedkyd7gIiAc1bnJYMV8BB8mPZLYI/CCD2DGuRAm5qAPj8piphJXUgfmOp@2lPPFHZm4dG7abY5YGkY/0hke4f4KMAGDbPYC1xyOHHbm8LVtz0xjCcRuj1/Csus6nvc7wDzT7UsetGfhyWPGKAh6ruP5I97AGvWWQLweDnDTh@n@o2HYH7SAQByH5gDP4MftO84igC32@nhJLl8Ge41whpM2GwH4yeGXz88iz7P9@u5zaZM9O3q1N/MoCqAie7F/cBa8bvFQP2oxQPHN/osXs6/igV2cFVbcSqc1TYMffKbpQ09t9Z0PkteWmxryZq6wJefTF1MTOjA3mcxt12qZ@U3ouG7IjxPQvcIDgE/5Eccju80mHRL6nc2@461t55NJQ5de4nqvnTzfF2B5uFYekF3btMehhfcnjIfLPeGBXuh0rW4PdMq1EwBAnbpgLV3H7@d@AIkZ/Yzu9hjxNMhvLqQ/Dy49h37fAA/Cxf28I@k6GN166w9lBUNavJK@xaW4xCF/7twb6S5e9XWGeo0u2WC4ibKFx1rTFii0FWgbIR1CbYKW25EknDG0Oiwnaah5CoWd7eL2znphO729s71RhF5sMZ0vpKGbvrWTS@dz@e08dM538untjZ31DdBxEFrc2ZISoEysTjYL6j0vy/S0bAMPLqzgCZCO1qtJibbZQeFnE6WtskQ78BhvM3l9@zzHIKIs4ZLUtUlVLmzgevH1PMvLkqwzgyUODnZzBwey/AxfcAR0NyfLbXwpbudyW89k2aSQXdDDBYjUw7f9TRwqlWULX3brBweI4QO@FLYRhyxf8hD@0vdftgDMxpf1dUTAZPnbAF0OkDucom2KNeIvudyzXVkec/K24Q/g6vxtg4jdxxcMwEgHPGQXwmT5Sz8S2NiyfMLhRFLP/fzW67J8yF/qdUTxFWW@yDP1Nb7U6QORXHiDeiDLXXB0XdO0ZbkFTqwNsmyAy5jq4DcAFx6WYI90WZ7yfGBOZHlC0LpxKcsXvj@kA/Q8f673Rm2zyz9Tlz8NCDqEIGsy3j9offllq9ttudP6/pcnFPTVV8/1D9Ox2@q2RMTWBXwcjAVBl4Pp7MfEoIsLvb846GsIsmeCLqYXJlF4oX8LlIlPFxMaXHyFQV9B0KKhN4EQPgMAbuHn2QCez/QWD/I/FETPSasll1Fksep0FBJcPU2PFlkiNwwXC3mK/oR0YAn1n9MB82W8rWaKT8bb8uaWXFqDp/xEXgcnVA2WS@YYk5Pnsqw2dppP5K2iXEo@eZJJPs4/YfLWjlySt7agCVfLt6g@FfWmo0zSk2oOPLLZClZorILwBKtCmARn5mSkPTdxlYqRybyNfSqVtwCHGyVxl9ur8QC6INekQ3Cpu78s@aL6DBRGrmzjLlYTX1cniYlUa@sjHbpMz27GpZKAvS13qw1E8Al/Khn5be2t3GTRdItbOaDqtW0UtiqVxvWnJphG1Xx5mtCr@cJ2eYLPrY2oUbTa173Ran6rUGqMVxuZfHNlJfepW5F/UiPUt5BZFh0WBY1VBj@fFVzHBVoKYuBuBfhmMhKGD6uibGSm4K0COJFHa2WUZHKrkEyqyTLEXZGB64LpNNeHheuXjQzaEcpmpwDRXXM0hrY@V76dS9m9LJGmxp1kmEKJyZtgkYE3bvRY9HkK/fx0aa1VrNT@ydznv/kniz6LffEjcRNzMy8lbqU2Hsq4sSMlbqTbm9tKzU/xazad6im/L80eM9ZNrUqrScx6cj3eeaxX692Tuj8wXN@VEpl1Z8NJrK6uSonKWU1el4@0i2AaqJalmcZznIjEuTrt/KKykvqt5ogyWu0pnzCugbHOspJr4qa2Nt6Bx6dqtotYFF3mJVK/5QcSkaqAUyrj2LqcQE1h9J0xrpmonPMMVb5L0FQOO77pjG1aPFp6iQa4ope4tdNoQnX97pXVv9lez9RozZMCMnZ7S3JhHNGqBilhO8IJjIQO0QgqrQL2elEWvRqTDU933m2923738vXR66MD9jRX2i5tI9/PQUrS@WQ@CYX4FJpk62RfSgw/OcX8d/ZX5URpmFzfSK5Hiu28mvBlXEHRVxq4U6ax3mw2QNiQXnivVgtP8sXt1EYpv8XURA33Hha2kN3oAnWQWU80ExzJxpYKbhqbL@QTtazwzm/l1YSX4W8QpZjwpMT2y/c4luPf1WYVyJWlrRirt5Vb@K/dskalckt9slvhwJ/bWx4O/5SP4I0/wk8EMAoThv92QqddJJrfZSr8v4I/u0c8p/JmUVYT76s1EIV3F@8uElJih8kFKr1UVnSuoCZ10eJbs@nP9Na8d2veWuixBlbqWvAGr5U1VqzlGTPXstnsufqjAthoOzub25sJ6TfAsTuWikNosHayY0KnB1T7gsWTddd6qePCUjtYQAmOl@OPeC/HU/9GPt@cY2jP4epgNOiifsLGi3jRRZZxv6mXxf1d6CtJ6LLoIlfWIRFE/T2iLUlsDU@DwU3oqnQjPQJcY2NEW8PgpyxJj3A/IL4qPlyaPfZGKg7M5VTp0SOhgL2R5o0uEDlGEp6ZfFm6lZA9ervtMboZB2dk@c51HTc3OUN@blp/yngkjy4v4bYpbTrHdCMEr7EOpwJys8YoRaIcM8eTf8TBWuMOknJw@GIf4kAfvUPLGEVs2W3hvVGUvZWOyoJ2BHiAl6dUBacIHAEBHXhy00Md4PZ4g6ozS7E8hndoOSRApVk@TZSkWUdEbOBrE6Ij@g5oNQ8Q89QVngO2diGSFXkQ9FAmgIWYO2oO6VoTt2ukRenhmeKNpspu/C2FCoayCiuokW2VhAsKg9/1ShGNQVvcgVMN2UzY8s00FG2Z751UAjjhEzLqVlobpQdlXlTDsvS1YoCF5LhK@bvB48fGu2Fj0Cyrg@oIn6nUAJroS8XiIGuj6qAK4jFsWM3yqJFKWc3qQP1awXe8agrbc2HnearIG@TcrgItuLzUU9MfG3bmO7uZPmjYKSB5nF77SfVjWq/m0EJLW9V8up/@Fkwdng9Ic1T9mLLLegW@uCQ4tq0VrJKUXo55YZRLpV/92NCbaPL1IWIqdQCZATq9Rj@VaqqQeB8C5yOW@48f66l@bVLuZzIqQr1bf3LQGIGjmarie0nRK5MnHxtjiF9S4FmFZPoqEA/xBK9vA9qBvjLwmJdpSDqnkSzSCZA3qFbXfvJk7Sdr1ZWVj41JZtBMc/aXcqE0IPETJL4c2TisrP1EZTMsoRlqRf7CKn2hreHuTyuVAianh5GYnMK1n0DIMJXyqb5FfXkW7TKjhImdhnxfJ91WQLtHqItMnWV@TQ6qi7pnWJYA5@c/DC08zQBPBErT/VI6QWCYuBIXA88nT55IftJicxukjMoFOuc6jljQxYi4V5hOxmD88KP79OsiNezr3KBvTXcdQS9@fTNSXUk1UYXzXKOBIKgGbnK3Za6x@JZGUDakPQCGtAfCZVCLIJOEnhCQVREIpeUXEMRCPdHhB3fR2UWon9C2Dmo@qBBOBlTmBWRY6Q9V0k0gTxa4mFWh9MABVUV6BJlAGjAPVpPVQJGxx4@ZeK1UWb6whW0BgiHch1QegeYohcQfQCngQCo/gIyiPqREgLZHGIL7xWMJbfxuCYmzIBSIkPqQ5kdCaHQkhDK2PX6ECvJN5WRgWTx69CFV3RAEwT91TSA@hN3@JiGa@xLbPXp5/Pps/@Rl/RR@oVO6Hb1Czr@ede5yxiFeutiybNp2augnefObrwzGFOyU4dUDePtym331@gUrFF7tpfHgYGB9go@1Q4NaCjCZHl3M4mmO281eW5dWNn6NPF6USztc6dL6jH/XnEmnMtCFy8HBLuG5Lh4OF0JjLk47jd3DNTA9T9w5mfHv76aj5uiImwGe1AK1UNxRSZuHYnv1cUVGmvZwuVbXokuZexxBLD7dVTXi0al@SHi3JHWOQaKlne1crsRyaXTkfUfBd6z7jg3fUfQdm75jy3ds@44d4cj7mPMcM3Sg19c3Q@dW6NwOnTuBcyMXOkMMG4XQuR46N0JnMXSGqW0EqW1uE16W8LlJVdd0MSy/se2H0bjDiDyLgCY/67kBhBbmICH6xpwnpLcd99zayYmEDrNHCFQobIbvoH182KrCqUpzOtI8Zf4mPKGtkng3jwR233VBK@1P8DJdEDq1xPBIBknCw8mMvqmDMWCOwEqpHoD8m2qJ2qCROy2F51Eghmo@eIfoeJMZxMnTfdBcfBYEFxYFc2yFhdj4SVgsYEzkZA5BJKeyFGtpOcaNmF8U6woqWOToEogCh8AyiB/k4ad55o4XJrl@d5IxhAuTnCOK4y0uioW8UQh51Y9K7T9hq/rpcTvFpNIGMwBjQqGTDMwUKJ7oVb3Jl@Rff/@n/xv79fc//xX74c9/9f/@x/8R3f8Bf/53PLGiEAD87OeMlpbAz79itJCEFrWEkQh@vST/8Ke/hNf/4d@xH376cx70J38hpzcCRBCCXmHMX/wz/PkD/Pk/5XQxAPzFH3FAjCKnb6WYaaUA1M/@mjFIDbEEyP70LxmTU2BgKELyGryONyOn93AEARsa5GrOhvNfvEMVeJxTUzLgFW/58C2FBaBGkLs6Xmcf1j0wZ/jYJmppQzd6eBCG8HI8tH8MNGEcT@uCvF23wegRQxJJyP3vsxJLphAGB1bwALMq1@Ei/yLfchiKsCk5C9ThLYQCFd0wG1AC3VsJ5Jt6AlNPw24L9UjzXEYEf1@Z0Ez4DYjsSxZduCmJtPzYOCQjLh@nG1j9ri4KLTZD/AAwunhUEic15CMJxtTNTLFBKrM@0GUMj/CJRiUPczDEI2iqIb@RsfhCXEjPogtLTlSb/aODmQqDnxaYmJdRjRQkVGWyfA8sclrAq2hxrcfhOb0CoJErrTdjhwEtApZ//OMfy1LEL4cy5LYVwhDJFFcZQVA@HlSIBBUiQVZH4CRdUywUZmighgP1YvxILB4toqLi0ULhwprjlwOSAX1BPiCa7vTHXq86j5o0clzZzSOPoMw3q6KenNukc2pMVuciAM54nOpsWS5GnZuDmS@oxTGR2zGfWGktxxSLE6kUxD1plktByeV3FpVcPME7UOebqQcmVMj9jgllHpjQZvH@hGaLFePG0C/n7/1qx1cTgYYPkfGKn4g1UNg0/imIXqiOkGKXnIoKXZ666PK0rh2mLLhlHvyz/k0Bsavl3cj9AdiJwbOd@PDA06EDXQ4HrWC/q6Tb7LUAj3U7@N2/XdtxTS96ypK4DthO4uFXhtO1oVVL440F1qUpLoU2xWGl8XYlaNmEFYpnQkPXB1FzRqHleXFh2dbo4gKMz35HDRmIr5qBhwMkJQMigisSXwlM26Oh4uDNKyP1fpxk7/JoZ5ZxqRwNRWASEqkz6NAZZh86X6yHN2j71yFjFvmd2mCRtkYKnY7ccwZO17QdPPcLY8@gPwxxI0H6cEi0pJmeZkaEItGJVoy0roqoX392VPZ1Ae@A9@MX4ghizEgzd5bHyFl3QXIXS5Pj0fz0Tj@f3tMovad309uxXG80SzN54mgPPj8v6XUlxACAIRnr95ORFudtzpETIyXw9tAuoggPJrFNy6raSGkdQOsCXOuAfKSDN4@OARCEv1nG/7sL0I@@/9DiI2P2dAr6ZkCXrVMXzfNn4RUAP1TVcKlkJLlAtPcemJbo6FAPL81kUlw2njEBFXM4NO3wtmsf8T0yjwur5uSeVltVeeACmtyrNLssLC@ivYu22denZlsRkOkIXj/HJ6beJn31sIyjoiOlB30AGsjMpfMxU4zOAiKg0hKR0dNXqrpcrDiIFUgPTcYRhYfL@UcDd7OqGQdBq3wOxHFBgyboIFs6d3g4HU75@WF9OtjP16O8/eEl@coRJwfeyRDgA7/FPZ8Ok1XvUp8nSpClB7QIAawWzzKdwuE3Ww5Y43Nl@Hksuj@nNMoQRKr6pRyzTpaVuHVXiUekwpdJbpU8TCTvE7oHy1xE1DiyUIXtfl4TMod5V@/3DUOJYuQ@d5aYY8/pBPTDEnPsJa3KxQKFGsQkTTfCm2Kr3L5QJQuch/C8gucbeCJC6INecIHy84Z2rT/kRSEDfRixWoRPw0BbNMJFNTqPGIGSfDcO5N4GaRpL0zTm0jRiaQY1IJ5kBEgyYkmKUsDiuasI@mZntEQ7YxD23OFxl9qGj@3oLs693iStZMlKs@RVsgQKOWkmS/sKKOVkO1naI4eXLJ2S4zJZ@hocYd1KfkqW/GqBAC68kuMp@gsVju9GsrSrqLfSCE/x9tPVkqWgTAHmCX8ljtzy4dWWmPV3glFV00xzozLNUGI8eDiYrUYzTd8c/PNTevmx8hC4UmWFNQLGDkis0Yi0GDwdaDa0vnNtusqi5qPkD02J8Y1wDAXCU9XIoApKyZj0UTKRjCsjThiG0uAjPIFA1JulxRSx/FzP7D5yROogoVTI8fSJexrZA22FwhsAHB3E6Yfx/fKKo@AF@DA6MfIyOufI8ZMjinAxgLqALGTq@@QdmcKynjlonJd@tITmxwiwEDM@CC8lQhvR6WDDoW1KiQ2dYVxIKBRn@6xoHPyISonSOxONtIKomUuCyVvkDBVDtPKrd2UnEg9Ji6kgDGzkmryWBe0C6WIMCnVdxFLllQ9IiOicNh2waKLY7gknwXF1k6a2Ylkz5MflSZLmiqtJiKzhaQpjfcRTD@dl8IyFz@u@@jEneCeLgggiMYNUuH51PsN@d7j97hvUPhNmElhkWC9uSufN6ztb2RnK@2Gy8wWIgWm2py40joIUQpZD7yBimd8la3Mm/tj2jXyeaIB9xtr32Rb0Ce7h22zfguNCK8G9inte4sDsZWE5o@Ytkv6V5hstGqYk8PCMB5SGWbubVp7xRUWMIdhGw@OzC9iNF3C08BAfZcCdYTmv5e7YpuVVYd2mY/LCmQs@6@DgKrHgaPyIJ6h7Wr8WLNECj6OLk72jVy@@gUZ3a2tLnZ@KwFoLccN2XLpzmiDothTSeMAsbsmjtRM9xx2tnNvy/JIy8gBjQKd5Gy5@oo6rQpdF9PlM3YV4HDbCUYHrMqwGekwroamjY5NtCb7ymyyVNV0g8c1b4Heaems4a4TSgRM6FxfUfF1c4OKciwvRimHRBNNIv0kwcbiilIivYSI7y5s7uxG7/eMB7bTyh93EqYx89UkC8ByO/NhBrLE9svwlDjgqRFsw/Rl8ZT2PYxKHncCH6MClGEphAzuuhSIeScNjITQOd9KCSpHOCjdv8L4db@jYdLw8HdlLxjre/uP5A65E9ti@1mnxB0@FTtKJUMSXYfmzYY7Nr8LxeFzc60kDxz5v0szsajTPU9iBjsalNeSnjgcLPjyVIhHBtDILeNzqmwMg6RQkdsEY8ksLhKZ3YHW7ID5ZcSkrX9ZypkPUjNPJ7PqnaSbYG71vBdeLiJVgdE2QGP0Fdiqx41A9VtgEG2onDZwNv8BYXBzD8MjTHC3NIij4bsFjizu305G4K8pUnX@u51eUCyxRvrHecvHi1SvdjvCXPp@iA9FiipJqfWSeEphri5MUk3iUYnASpySOZK7SNKWGS9SGipyQ/SM60SkNXRPVdSbP10/ofcM/O1TBU2tL0iObNBAuBWMGX2QDlq6N1hvNs6nB2lSbfcHWCxLdmeTQKDMnAHDwKb4YdgiDqJgPvsxPaBr5i7b8Bc4qSo8SqBS5@GF8X7rRTddhhOLNVgQ6XO8qpjB5tfBfipEXrB38liPIOvZGNoHCBZSsKHIK0KZkVeaog/iz0cU0ySOuoucxpXGm7pFgNWD5zWev3zZd1yYw6coBQR44eE4tX3tcvmM1MC0HxjWHscXASHR0dWdHLHrjF1im5de4bKvEE6EGR8Nzm1Hfl2cVfibvr/GkBy6uZmu0A7oTa51kFyMHZKxY9l0EUDNEgo5qitaMfeGV4As0pH2UwCZa5qAQb9R7aSOO4OJrPE0j1yxH2iElH6UGCex4oI86wM@0TBedPIaI1C5DI6kusrVy5Vh8IM4b2rT8W85oMkUVS5URUxwFL030DxbMSrRK3td7d9xEoWfz27nNHVp0zez0KD1o7DTTa0ZVZubI0u2BN3av25ddp3cFFgYbfmhNjOnHbxkrbjDclVJ4zE8MyG9Ws3QowBadqrGTox0h/pkedO7EucwYbULGE0KSjAW7lMoreFQAfNL4U5LLc1LK1ga@FPKV14PGZrNqV3PlQcNulu1USh2lqqNUPqWgx@O8WgZFzcdqGqMmLaXMrrGX/npHPKcZB2SdDjt2bKPnJD1G12BHJwJp85lfgQb6MFqfrqCr4rhRnw7Kkz6IVcR5L7pBciam5fhwo@nQRDUaLBXtOyC/@PNovLlRng/HHD56hOuay8KgjWbgRhqOW33LAPVE/ES7BNc4lkpipb7BUG5Bd6GfxT05LdCAKRhc9kMNZzgVkS0OcuHnpRJBWVOw6VPTD4H0oVogkxd4q4YLYByEszcGzgA1tWAqpwrdL0w7aJ1wc4VaxqXnbMUP87dhIDzKDW2GuACbkbZOwKPCBCgtTGaqWAZMvg0LVyKQfVdL8qBHH8aDIZkHGqdXcAQvs7sY6pYbxNS8MV7cqbA8MsPyicYSQMctbua7Ams0WjR@WeBoBM2IY34Q3zGd@w4EGzreJgy6EWeEEF/boTiP@DWLCjSYfLSLkyHiUjZUUdTAODzzLTlMlhgNTpTBi5qfciT0A4RiXpcEDyB4oI96S4J7iHvsLQt2IRgvX1wSbEEwX6iyONyBcG6ILQEY4dAbiOvFyLkY6VZf4auscX32LVfYCkulfMYGIsB4wfDyiMdnYr06W@Glw4UtJl5QP0msOACKtCIqD76H0kKheDKIwuUikibnCbth9yYmRqyAxReUEqhdTF9di@FnEQKg/oEqZfPhfuK8tIOMxuRH4xdwQXAFdP6nT3dRJgQxLn/5pi99vIRwcDSSQ86tEA@/xS0sVx7po4i0OI5Yzx/Vbr7lGubDr5SFUIXwuhXW644FtiVEVdHKCb2xH6qyJ6FPw2uyUqA9Qj7yanE/Hwtz0oPdVKqRadYKncbDuaqj3ENMHVrkVqgscPOWXp5jpxdAZ@LQNYAOuDkjZ0ZMZkQt/dzMPiw3CaCPKjXxpswVrQGmYU0QuIA8nZdrVCdwZKvJEvfHa7@sODJrCTK@yfECEIwqQAO2bL4a99tEy9b4QiHQ87nCRprG/TnIbcgmX1k9hE//AJULGSea7DHehBJXSWwBa@bAg3wjv2qzVW4me1zTL85cg680Sz5JIo1sXp5I6p5AK1liORbspimz2/v10G/HmZuw@GL2jqcs1xV@ofuS@BARvF3C6HuFLJ6FQpPFOI4kkGa4p0minaGLG6VwvuPC9/HHwnjdXmqBIVXleDjSzBH6AWAoR2Olhc1VC1Wn2BJ7MfKNm3RoheEFZFwqwGQvS1F1jt25A2q8o77Bfh7iSDQElxeihen6lFkd37YFM9iPpxkXWMycychPqNNdx2krvsEkDAbC4C@bBqA032MUmFXcvAyTh@SE0cu6Yum13@6WwWdFeFG7Ah5ofArZRCLWulRtylhtIvaN5dH9eBSOrREk5U8J4VgS1z6sNOuP0IEJ9GhhJF/j40Yx2k4s9Dy1xDH1IO/qNo7b0bll1LWuyOgfFATC1KCjHW46pjK4XTDKwDdWiy3HN9Gui1W2NLSJg0IXvXbopgfUVCoyJhOe2PGbxEp27LnZlmVnTfsKjOrWVEoEw1slvIM0s42jt3iTqNAmNFhOA0IgJlBSmJpmm9dKcDMpjj1IfKMgDSDlJTxWggbz@@ZVG6x@vox@6HgT@p1CZyGnjYcjh0JEQrShkH2yPoWb3HM0tSt6DIKcCuEJYRSc9OG@Uz5ulclzAymPR2aoERQNjEkKVz6XZSw/JFQM@zWakqeZutFDIlD2PvHuFBQXSfKt5PlFjxvgkBU4owjOPl/6O6RxPEyCrBNvSu@QfXzPo4P70Egkyr3op0g0XosheFU4CjkOy2H8CjCAM/7R6dne/smJJk5r5tMIOPXAh5lx3QbtIhR3jotRVpxCwD2cvFAeYWYRN0@vGiIn/Us8wmQFm7AqXCM7Oa9wkyjPQSZPb3PZCOBVDk4soTlo8eYhL3NiqfUQ7CjkXRhNiUTL@NF84AgrHt3LDd0wcHXuS3PgAMW7Zr8PRHNePArZgU7kiJ9@Kkjfa2CazYB4Hp6ZC8/EwjUezokKoTSj54ZApSiQnLgJ4W6ZHIKl59KqMsj04Sva8qM5boTu8l2wngadNCsErgVFyaUyCKjEAjKRkHcLSp@HrMTiBAIehDd4uJDvgij5gMoY7NN4@viURAGZtDBWrCOZkVLNtvpP@PBjEEIaluFeFx4dy5vEjldKMSAi1EkG1AReH4/VtlYNsaTyvsahOiPXKk9lTQxJPVFmyeAD3nMVa0EdiXCJ0kwR4ybUkkA6FLwSQUE4UdCYX3NrfuSpiDyNoEWoFT9Zyd@@Ha/gkLXZKl7FIfRP@ONX9jhxPlxiceAjTvmEZ55PhMUZREp3RV7Mprg2Gbljk3uKTN3RioRpT2cxLlYSrxzsgRo91BRBmiafrus4Y7u9EuiJqKLwNcUc34MQwekQIO@L77IixMBb6TfZNelLfQBWYd@csDra1DodtCTF5kLxTnEPDy/DozaZNx4O@5bYbMeuabZNHENUKOLEUIgxYjRo0iGu2uHwaXSJuUuIpLEjxHxt8bu7RYA37nb5RcwMb3oE1YrXq1sjTarbU35HNO5NK/AZSXG7OyrgPnT7IkTwkuO1J7h3W5P8E3h4Vju8fotLw3FWDi@AhiatJEk/GlvG5e6XrJDLbeVz6/kIy/yh6py2vkFXTfsmkh9QyOVzuWJ@Q5J2neGUrzdRDBVxbWQQYZq9wIb@DcgmXoxum1IdWgwCxFM6PdO9MtuaJJ2YbRoDbo2JIyjKdNW57W@@Rx@wrfAQIrys3EvzG8lBwvCJ7TM/UMCg1c5pCad4h6Y7sEZ8Iti5svAO9WBau@P0@841DUTjjDLnB0YamCNgyprK4iTRYQGCFrJdaA8/cEMXF0brLeeKDvcQbAA71cIzkWh@VsKdrYghmhi/bTZCCaRn9HVrgOK0gADc@hJywCcAstYeG@adNEhExGfS4N@E3XaMMR6XoPslkwXt51BdgepuuhZo35DBVCoULUI7FPDZ88NTdnp0cPa2frLPwH18cvTmcG9/jz37hp0932e7R8ff0Fm07PnRC9Aup6z@ag98X52dHD57fXYEHnL9FGLKFCDVX33D9n98fLJ/esqOTtjhy@MXh4AN0J/UX50d7p@m2eGr3RevobH@Ms0AA3t1dMZeHL48PAOws6M0pepHk8J47OiAvdw/2X0Or/Vnhy8Oz76hFA8Oz15hYgeQWp0d10/ODndfv6ifsOPXJ8dHp/sMMybtHZ7uvqgfvtzf0yB9SJPtv9l/dcZOn9dfvJjJ6NHbV/snSHwsl8/2gcr6sxf7lBLlc@/wZH/3DDMUunaBeUDgizQ7Pd7fPUTH/o/3ITv1k2/SAunp/o9eAxAEsr36y/qXkDlJuYcrUC67r0/2XyLRwInT189Ozw7PXp/tsy@PjvaI16f7J28Od/dPy0x6cXRKDHt9up9meP8MJQ04gFsQDu5nr08PiW@Hr86gzXh9fHZ49EqFQn4LjAEq6xB1jxh89IrnFph0dPINYkU@UAGk2dvn@@B/gjwlbtWRC6fAtd2zKBgkCEw8i2aTvdr/8sXhl/uvdvcx@AjRvD083VehwA5PEQBwYrpv65Doa8o1lhPQxZ0grJIvuWkqTnZ4wOp7bw6RcgENEnB6KKSF2Lb7XPBcw9NyF0653TmBNz/LJ4ZC7j65Z/dobx8sPn6Ynxz6v4ZGZzs@eRcLg4YmCIRXMQtKbdVF22yNuxeW3XGwax5E4zPYA6@bxiMxVbww6Fy66447PlFOERKJi4s39Qvo555eXKjph8SMkXFfDLE1/i4oVeSx7@ht6ubHxpaijKo9FgfwpPlpGNGxlsfB4IPKstm2KaLhQhJE7A8TiZOiAFkbNSOtMNFtFkmSppjjY0V0jNnsYJE/vel48GN/Cl942xDxAOXM1y1ks9iHJTLwODoW0A@J0Elt4rg2WgdgdShJzTPNy66SiyaHXX4xQKX6cQh2BN3ArqLeE71ldmeiZ2bjE7G4AoiMFf@MHv/sHH5FN74JljFRLppLOVP40B49VJ8aSgiMQpUnRcuLxOoT5TGPjpu@@VihWg7Od6Ez2l7Wf3z4FjtzucJGecb/eeDP6xYuBcQDB6G9a1C8Jj2eNzkAVDALu1/AEmvKp1Sz2UgcsMrIngyA8QChHgJdW21oU7Gp7pnUrOOxRfwMh2h8aIxdaxKlHtTwlyf1l89eHxyA5kRqN7aLW5tlSRyD5I5@nObPbzAdOr0XuQtW9LUFZhoFRWrJLtg9B3MnGEaOXMTSQ0A8N90vNPLEK8qD7czcRuCHnvFhIMyuh8c@2XjymYwnN7kyw0WT5orky@vCmikEQIllVcXcDPQJWfg6mEokAwbfutyfUqlN8AdxB9Xfr@JBhoQACREzB8PRFCQXOhek9@QDfxUo9W1oiReCaLIvx0PdX4PEGYM6k5bG4hJJehOyHSlFsGuxoLG@UrFTTCBiZZYK/@Q8OgcTkjh2PL8Gc08LfH4s5A2c34gTGzEIz9@qj06BjQdBzIx/oiIfcxYVQ2Bu1qpQRI8fBylVGA6kqoIoPv4fP88vWhuIFL6ggc0g9lceBXwOQmgQ@mlSZTdcUvGoFcRTFhIr3kFyF2VHYCn759SId/9YP8Zxhaf8kdd1kIbkg3zjgwTsjLHpd@IH4f@vyJMF@CvQ4QTsIbdID1v22HwgJwkr5xX0Xokp1rW/YiyyTC3kZtTrmxDNbbRgekHGxDK8CZ9YAhaI0pn6Ht/wc16VBQxAIcdxjWj9xVMVqBL3dOg5PaW6@4jP9Lu2MRgq/impflMxh7eZJpsr7S@RwxeVT@HnWCS5F3jo3VPafEs6AztcoMVaU/aFJ3McqTzpHMx0do0GPYJaTqKJbMj7NTwUp5yoWn7ln4gVRmEr0/ZDb8EUXX4CazAdggc9xhS@PwPiKxBa@xTNsGAbpFlDQhfmG5ff0yg/E604Hl0OKpDaZXZGq6c9vUN9ZmyKxFJnXFONSSKeL9riIM2WObrG5qLPsdMS7xAbU76gVeaYiBiLDMwIX/mqGnCdGtnrgHoapkR5Dah/bV/aeGWIyYe4fAgtdixndF@8xl7qdEJn/2H5lsPEU8jWWjz9Q5uWvRt8vhKH5qjnDqlgT/8LL@QIWJzXaF1COxRySTcu0VP2ZdS6zlgTeFBaGZFz/6BJ6DPQMcKLjP7bpR0ClJWZNbBMPreDQaQSb8iqX/jmC7p43Q1c36BLjDNXIVNAHPjggllhBiHJaDfhIs352kb0BXsdClKCFp@WwHK6vtZa@nig2x19YPWntOr0g9Ozs5499obacIq3n8ZHA@kKFIAD2kcme2vZbefaY8@gOuBA0umr16fH8YG/yMjXLh/5YuwrSIM9o5SlOfQd3MjiOZ0RFI1ZZlNxw5QbDvfQOKEYaaFhrSl64G4hlwQI0h0ElvGXr16zL03bdMEePKY1l@yFZZg2qA8wpmgVptfjmgbBDzD1U5E6O0DbhUZ2ysy0aFAnGNuTRAICWxpFS4GqCAS74qxrHJufgqhHxgS1@QyH@Wr7g0o9Zyg2a@CgKRqbfIizM@6nJTxQ@@3h2XPsjPOOOY3NQLPmj/XhWCI3nQZ8sBYy4@r2aApMkWYHb4Ds@8ZuNEZ7NQCjtJyd1Kkb4E1DbRz263uQVbweTGgBakGgqprWFZ7gS8NwDykjWmcrhs1CvpXFpte0uHZHqI5Y6Ulh6aXxIHctzYo77MxE2WXHfd2AHhY7HWP09XWwA5853ghBX9YZyxXy@Xwmv45DtK9P6xpVBPz6x7pK0uHL46OTM2CkOLfIF4ygzUTm00mqfDUWsCOD56lC7t@jQvbhQWMW3hPz0AT3D1eQy3zGQi7JUPaGjsO9kEMvbg7TkCwOyTsuneaKm3VAhGLVEVL1rlH58qkRSimCPU3nyYoTYXnTEtBJWywpwnukrQ9y1cf50PcUmfxAAZgT8oNYLvUM2uIsIiiTgTkIqLdGfuuucwBp9iDagGF8LBWEI5lOopUE3FOjeNomrpHw8EingXdluKBb9CsQOVzC4u9YApkh3aQGudFbVt@COgB0GT0HGxyurvyCoCGI6DG1EpV4cAAiNkhEy4IjpKB2tZ1BAMqpkqRgh57wH3pTw2GJLnSzsaflDU2zTcdXjYf8fCYM16CW96Hl4Hv3SuHBTVIiR@smXVA2eE4e6L5xHzf04wbMFi9zyc8NSJW/5/Osh916jghydDqiSorH6CoLethphvO8KhW7DgKBcVVkxJLdl4BimMZJKaAKypsEglwkLmm6KIvKe3ZzJkakEyK9YTwAcfFZXTMe4KPHvAvnHAAX0mpAwMy@T58YvmeJu2NjYPEXzC@uO8U9bQrPI2RuqgbMPLDwXHM@NuCwroO/CKz5HONzhCbNEc7tJsW7QPOAbxYyPw8JUMGpbhHIwgKcmYU41xfjzAicYrLy0L6i/XQYi8SC54If0eGAfkRGhNn/0vFVL@366zt8ginIfbfvtPAwTdAUkBo@pumwYKPe1AOLMToaynd2xg8BrfhZEqSLvU2@7cIqUD/MGqv4Ixa1c5sXlAio8rpE28cYtV1UnciJP6JGkVOOnSiKVsfMkaJIHvcF3Y1oZYFS@MglFtZMXIkThRcpx6MMYlHyM1EEcfEorViUghRuH58pXYyBqh@f8Zz5dgmtSqISYNWggHLSQJ/w3k2ONgPSMA2e4x3buFhoCgFBwIbBgv2FCN6UwnMzYtP2PA3/lZbg0YpveVWmc0hz8UOoJv7SPVIDBBULn9LZLLYiMqQKNtBLcCaH6hMj8lWhKHZEUwUZ5gFSLNsu7tVSoqmoJZYY6nzWEKE8bNiiSTeIBzhLL8PfGlNEApkosRwIzzoQqhAYT@dhNKAry4vF14M5KWyZ6S2i4KAEJa6/ackYbwYUJVavfM0d4OTOOd0NqNCfo6OUJL4p2wO7jvtiixJRDado8OHZ8sLIMyfQPaM5ZkJB7U8wYi08@UETgfYQxDfClJt@qxHPxVLo2aZkEUykVQm4cBewz@yAT0uBl7c2xDocQ0B9x8EjrHuBg8SCdX4TnPQ4y8hKsUa0F90xLK6h4myLKF0eN71AAceL3CcuPZMrKXK@jMjhbDMixVrOmJAokTe8O4d9wU8X5ohUKRYL@b@swHG5Y7RiL4XLczhR7MskIsDll/tdYhEA@@V@l1hw4Eix3y0W/gHTAWsp/qxcxEqCswAXJYoeA40pRXWQHzCJQk1moIigaTN6wIzZVxZQG9GqYqxTmjOVAhaJ8@TiadBjwgtGXFkWF0dgXiMojWaYW2jjjEuzHRyTIXIfdJFqcrxJ4KU5ezoUZtpPgcqoqeI9JkEE0Nh8EEz0mQd87SYdM5TkHRbqg@JRqt1efHdvDK3fquTUeYPSP1IpJL6ykPjM/NFWYRerNH9pT7C6TFCNC54ct43QsrRgxle6h6pUhKp47iIlFGfxEkyZB2HKPABTNoJJVOx1aC/JmXDx8GDzPhTn5/M46PEOOlICB2jatoWD2NgPvtan9@FcAWMrQWvqdL6qLIgQ2sn34Xgyi4MOa@8Fs3HCs6fjqNtH03Vmj0pbytm4rCygKKAqMU9WGskirU39XQHnm0rUt9UuWz0r6Akk7i9pfqaEiIxLiXvBJFAiftRRgCys//kl/EtHijVeHzjhsWEYsJalz6wOGjKCjzDxrWJBhIgii/dDRUCcEXeHzio/6q3OnjSBp9Avjabem5OnfMAnMuiUh6xxjRWTOL8LFyonv7Xy9dui7tm96ScWpj90hmDjdBYSQPADHMfng1IzKj00TWe61g9qyxa2Z/P5itptMwfGPbySP57LegGyjhvToVLb5rVo/e/CLPLil8BvYck3fBlZQuQXC4nEiXZdDG4xezxoma70kKrOY2j44H2k5ZIrSYkEqxvQZRYHF9G1UXSmsimSRDMYBcFj4yHO13h8cSdWbhwjM7kAz8LiXfYErcmYBI3RDkzdFicZiQaz6@L8RQCbxjPVcXMXpWDZBjDaMyPDn@/5RSFtU4TgiuQ72FpeXPYo1ZimoCIdpiTI4ramMo33abnvEgMnsGoIqjRrqPiyg5Oha9wyF/YSGObq4iGwh1hPdxlEIMTLkhQd3hnUd8toaTkzx8OAlUHRPICVi8ytYJT7AebW9KHm1n8FTs4WqBRxC@tBNLCle5XabCefbsn1T8seLDi65c3ZwUHswJPW1O8VDEy3mMvl8BCcuSvxcIICZ4ktJxuHzuKYeHZ4/ZX7ppXFqPFL8BbegYc0AChC49QEyglOTYyhvYmcyoXjOTbuyvngcUh@Ak@b0TJOK1jc/uaMhI9QIvPMEnuPGcT8vWf@HdVgOPIug8DirzeD2GiGXsn@MjlgD3p08ESdYEkaIaN@s9i1gBMf1dqN9EjcC0njfHiHj3oTbkOUn5v9vpNmbx23316R@e7QeISDg2iEHAfBpYS88nh0p0SamVdWP3KvBoJErn/nFzPhpbt89JP2MrnmEGfSFGzHTszu/mSoyI13MggmZDmF2UwxuYnbe7oyNFEyTaHfj5YfYwZkPwh6oA8Vg/g0CwxtoNhLFbqAonW8eZOvDsbxlF3IMi7mUGIgKj8XhvPsfmhk6mJytQ@OZSuQdQyWcLscbf2m4qWcLAEPmCufT/Id5GGO4xA04bmJD4txW8ZDp377D45u48gBbm6kMd5gS2zkvLFoPvzBeKxZ7GrU6UD14iPxNf@oMR8dqcpMnlYpIGtEwbrmt2OwZ5RkxxPH3uFSm9OpbcQIaRSaaSYOxyv/bnmU/Booqh/wE5dNfJ2Ban0wpstVQn1Gw3C4gGJe72CEC4wgSV8Y1W@vlXq9zlaHqRSr15@BI5Nh9Wd1tocez56xPXh/hu@Pq4ViscxXzu2pN@D5zPe8Zc8ABzVBeJHbHrxCGN3PhF0pLOLVbHU1XV69qFZqZS/bqD9rZrNdcP3d7//07/7pn2Tr4uV7fHlGL413AZCmadlV42b18W0Z3xt7zeRqq7E6bCa7ZZQyVPevXU/v65FtYprxD3KZrr9z3lAZWLRqtZpkyU@fuOt8FDrd0Ik3H4TR9f6wp1N0Rhhq1WQ9@fgxuCrV5E@SKp7cIfz1wP8j@DMVdTnNFxNrafq4frp7eBi9XCi4tLSDliZOuOticZplexZk6n3Cnz3PNJimsWaGvQ/IwwXdFxwwTiJL4opRTsx3gkg/d7T6nlapUsJ8@SktMOLrnvhqtIHXpeVF/gIlCqPFYBjpi3aJL50jHClQeAhf5ptSFV7dMPtALq51q2Ya@f@vvWvrceKKwc/Jr5hN1E0yZMkGKJdSkOCNh7YS7VsWbWZnJ0ukbDLKTAoRyn@v/dk@58xk2JsohYoHUDaZc/PxsT97fOzHP7876na7GBnRuacpxBxGy3194zQIlkWkm2TUy@nI0Nq5N57yJKIOmRjd7k8pzeMw1TwOSxSU5AUjX2Gv2wtSY0Q0pUxKEbZc/d4IaENvlrGGxexImW9w3ZqxwfamgXs0AVc2PfoUoaRvRyrVboMKgkH1YM54Ui8t7xJ0@uLyqC1vHaa1TAz1DoV4ZN2Dg17oGu1vghv7TDXVEj/RI3uzpDfuV4vtxYIrbuLSRPGBpBNRfqCbtVhaVkQeQVqeZTN@8SknWjbMX9oDMMz4Luwy5bcLnIR0wZl3BfBZrWVCkHQeGOFoHo4Z3/nuL5ZyVWA1o4@k8DkhotSUBhveQ3InYSh@qYYUMdLe5ECcE3bN5UmmKv3tw2zBHhzkrQEarf2Ay3ygLfFCTzktn3BE3/idVQAY6Enq4Ky4kB1ClZdsgrJThIjCT95HwloSDdtoulhOm2pNI0oRQ8owDyQSmSSWG2auL14xnFz67QxkNZzedpmUSt58VRRzDVTRbUIUjtwSXlOvJ722DKbcElbjjnN3osL1GStlH4nP2Q8mOUdodFqkckHlQQ7e5MhDiYvrVuJxUZKdRe5ZVs5TuSolox@YLM6RDoS/lbwpnx2IjAcJB7UNxggnkd5C1UhQbLXvB3TiW8l8/t876J2AZhZiJPO1rC35xDGH250TTyTfo@MEdFAlis4RzimlYKvCmIvsYl5W2gzl0rXeL5VV7Iz0fMiniHgMqFujLMcGWTlsJxKmSm8LwmbBa7@RoH0q0dXNvGeLYa0msViupSwJiTOe7vOHk0c2nXDWdIKJfHx8h9UdgnJlXTcvhI9lTzyrRn4XrhwBnesURV7EuMmPDlRa1GlyNOGiwDVqkDitHQMvhY8r3QcMzMwdanLIqBp5ZbsEEuwJb@MXm@muocj9vzluZSvP1pxqlg4fPcV8QDraB5Of0RPL1KMb12XjCfyQGVBn8TvH/aX1ZkHIX4LUVaOEdeT9oG4etaFs6brDR0BKuSUsm/TCvaw1tfX61u@qrY96krvhk2Vw6AdIJx9oYgf9tSXKnLSp9SupGfrH9ufOckhoCgYXmW67oySHek1mTB6OdWdp7jdn18QaZsOblLc1K7Lg0Jiwc/SF3EP6XBjv30CkHVw4rzbl6k355TE9fHeYzXzmvkStesIFCcFghQjJYKSf6OMEda@/kFnAcmBOgkBuqiRFRp/bbUEeamF2fisuXq8@9o@HJ52TznD8@NmgAzvZ4bBuWpBl1E0zjqhes5WQqe1Jmlgj5P7ORISvz@bn54Q4tOICNdXR3E@n2u2EPeSfnLgrjqBqOxDiWSeQ5cURbSK@UFrjc75OLi4TfPx99dc62b4hJYQ//1jKfv7J/b0lZcSVV/HLWzmjr84JanR2bCd7nrjREuEyTwj5pCWgQZlJqgQHFxoIkO0RQMZ06y@qiw3IEK5ffBcOPUNv0qZOBaEUEhs@lZyAU5gAfD2B7LRT@Y54U02YAvns5CN@EoOgDiD5B7vJE3wrLQTqL6KX3KaS0s9nVAPj9TGatBpGC2LQYzO5rl7KSm4@Tt3si6kaNmX6/vRysyjnurK9Zdm6uNEwElJsuCyJLpOzCHI2vPkLvgD1K35EemXD6OwyrNMuWAf3O5nTKfW2DASVp4IaYdZLYD8aubF@uB09aFBTRTK4P3gE/jjePb9ibwTdvzRTgxOscxK3YDuwXqZ5YG5IxkGnZyO36oOK8cHzIKLwNOKcZbKI5l24x7zDnAIewsRt7tew2b9nI1e@YZKdeiqZXaph1CLDvK2P@8PD6PgIbwtCq5Y4BY2L1aVFW6o5ERivQW1oOkF8g/y/Nlivsdwq6C8gld3PDLHLQeWgVcChXYwLyOlADDRzuAtYawhGQiQBkZNrBjShcydIWsm6vkFsiFFCT8qc6yDbEJNbaYN4oy72lOfQwYi9nwaG3hwCwqPEU@cmVFW7ecWmL4PZq@c1mM21iilDyB55Beoxa4MR7tjgWkJl@4Qa341QMq8mOskvX4xMVQJUqbRrt5vY14kOvTAannWXK2BPLoFwBw4I1/poALp4rxlMrN4dbaAh@2cGhuPo1QWJxSoWlqiBxH8nVo8YkEUtN5RzxMmVms06@4UQMaGrNv0jyMtSCvfjKh4QgqyjtnsImSCYGqC380ZobrJo1B209c3sSEKJ@uMn4wEGucFI7UrdjFvDexGD/CpmtpfmghUKIEccnWqqkOu1H3TdZ9zSlfU1uqRJInuntIjnOM/5yu51XupR1ypsRdR9NIju6KCGr@SB6CD284y67RZNQZAGB2zRYGh9Tx28RUbLyO3KjLhzfeIPsQ/N0f0t@b@NxgVS8jsOcADh2NAB4zPuVTdYEQJCCXFAez8VPSK1uzDfOIqHaoCLIG2Fk02Dj1VVNzqE3K5ASxfmUwTUDryKjV5T8xBF3cZmUV/u9yYLvDrKUnaEOy9VMQj8wep2GPUsWzRPS1KiuC4r4ipczuFhpHODy7qGMRoN/QqhZB4VYpwsRTjXWZeEEH8JwqtKoWPiUF/e6H@QB/QJfzoPm4EIi1ePQ7yHZuTpvlk6yjdTB02vog8v6GJVSyUAmkj9Okvy6GfTvi1B6/S8hknh0Pt@uPRWO3FTVnWJ0pt5UXTxk7Ho4lD3bIsRextY@0g@fsnogxQyXv9EcZhmqSX6F24K@k8YlOt2JaVLF0bSviglcnTggzyK8n5RQn09968f2Y4TnZScn5M63vBt/G1JXfBFfFSqC@gsjQqYFLdTmGaky/AqCsnE5KnULTNt7e2yCIZZYP5a/jFQaqYJm1rUHcKLkLOFX12tUskAxkGA7BxAXCns2rGYRWwQScMJ/6mJVFozyUc@05MsK4jiUx1W16DzwSIEY71eJ@WNIJZ/JSe326MlZ4PlWgM1Pizut7nm5m0h2U1wWXxjXNaN4dOOPTyLuzlhi4d37OPr4jTvoKV@Om7mHT6ocODD5CAS0wYttsPQma9SK3zldnfY9wO@fKuKIf7m4UvsyJ9WQUzsQUzaCGL8A9oqZccb2rnnIR7o2C5hIccKe2S8VXU8Ojc23qpxvCLjDMORf04brzAsf90wbPlhpS0co@qA8D82DsSyVs70tKNnexr19w@07LdXww9/qOH/sxr@Bw)

Transpiler is [here](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/ork/impl/ork-0.10.tar.bz2).

ORK code:

```
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179
```

Code placement is dictated by presence of `W` and `w`.
 The code must end with empty line without spaces.
Retina does not seem to like a lot of empty lines, so I added spaces to lines around literate CoffeeScript.

Test driver update: `...` filler for failures.

Answer (score 7):

## 180. [CoffeeScript2](http://coffeescript.org/), 9957 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111x            -xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO 8=,_      x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps    # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._       #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]      #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqTqTqTTcTcTc                            #
############################################################################                                         p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>x._++++._+++._^<][4O6O@]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                        _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyYyY
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"' pp
###;{a=1}={a:null};if a then console.log 39 else console.log 180
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=96los*81''ca
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss_ baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8SDBB15VKD662F1V5JCsqukBUaxEIgFkEchEZwIkUCy27Z5kc/s4k@5m587mdnXbM6uTac10H9ZOktmd7ZrJTPf1bH9E78c1meYfjNw9Il94kKyZXTuBBDIywsPDw8PDw@Pd0r3eb36TwA87dvrTbt8ZsZHpjVjbta5MV2PPpuypbnnFwrokIVTd7Y4Hpj3ySlKC5RmzbMNqwzsbOZembX00XfAvMDZ0na6rD9iop4@Y6Rn60PSYMx4NxyPmdBZHW2dsf@B8sDIYc2DZXQAbme7QNUcUvsHYa7uvD1ptfSakOJPg0IVwj@2Z/U@DTyNmOIOBbrc9gNxk7KXjeibCG6bnORh9i7HJvmnMIN0GUN21nBf1V1/OBO0w9iWQqA/75oTpLW/k6sbIcmzkSY6dvnp9ejwTI59nb84ODmZ9C@zrjGOzg7FxORu0zl67nt7XZ/FvsPp45ByOZv2LrN41bZ0VtB2tMBu4yZ65ejwKFeex67THBrJ61DOBAiyejtU3PckA8BobCqHQ0MESzDX1NgcDrKfOwIxS7THbNNvMG5qG1bEMQsTMyci0PUjQ05gFuby2@n3WNvsQIcRupJnnsLEX8Wr19Z5maFLHcRmmwgaXfWYxYzhkPIj1LSDpILfNTBQa9hHC@z2PTYYD5lkDCB4ZTqdjmuyjOewxqe1IDD7GcCZTwduqCTC26TPGHELhI2MclBXgks@fa1cfDiG3ggMjawCibY2SHjN1z8LKA1E8024TT4dBtXKYbkfZxa4sKFzI@Ngl3J7pYsFohJf1TNcElHog2Mq1a42Al8iLOjs2dZeduaapxqtYLElIzMEURpgRjYq0UknuHx0koWh5DE0fQlG662c/@krSmVZlqxdl@FZluSztv9pjN6vn6OY1Cop/6Cq6yqrfMS97fm7Cd5JvZbvurQRYJeBKn2Wd4SirZ4ZAYGYEBGZ1dKIrc1XQhv1IwqwyUxYRgeNQbSgNdmizN2nKmTF2XdQaIVP1S8h037G7wE/IrDu2kR8228xBERgOVPo0M6@Aa1DLqIyca@LwWc@CQvOwSCKVgus@YihoPxBiwVE/Xc/pjwkOYnojlGTgCkRFjIcd9oZ1dKuPUSAcUXGqXdMb90cYZ2y3seRBt5ltjflkGE4bgQbOFSSnA1LyAMEfRGolEQXAUBAOZRWDfvgXf9budgFP3TActy3E9Q1rOwZpaZ2IBdXHUGAdW@8TWQCXxtR5dEjgSu9bbX2EydtTkQQRQaleO@N@mzmQoHttQR3t6VdQr6FqGSOTCzlX7Gk20C@5LrG45ELGB3oLCpYSoLQp2xn2dBdKyTClBMlMZjAedbZZZrjPkl72nfKkpDxZOTeBOFVT11az2W4ZBE5bIy94S94lOW/qMd3njXTPsdrScDrqOXaBZQwmG1VnaNpKMoYjmU66raSqoY5T1LJVNbSOZbeVZAVksQYJJ9WyUTUaVqlZnokeTRLQXCMarK6mYqiyBCqHKsVVdqBbtjacsjcZ4YqEOd4FshyDtYg3MmbW74p7JKhhQ7l0UEBAD2le3zSHSk7Lq6gmEG5hvjFgUU5ncIgMl6xmKplIpqJZJwyQ01hGsbKeWQ6qrf6wh20aMMX2htAOuCi7hg7S42FzMALrIs1aJNfUhoBmIZ14bSZdk7VAkfpyRFWSVzmMn0FFKTCEVShek812pCKDEoC6PPLmtHHfuYYEiSZsZEB12Jio3oWigcg8I3WeEZ4S@cSzdGmDQkFsLZNtZ1oWVAKsbqDThcxH8gbg6wUOA9h4JYnonoE@BSwGb1TDCsOsDtSlAagHd8oME3UOKB@TNyiYyJjqnwf2FFpWuUyhWIzXsbkqNnKz9cxPQEl/zN5ZkzDz9ZjJAC1Px7xmfd3ujvUumnQ2RNENwxyOhKKCnHgjUEWz7Q15ZkTjqXk9afXpbNrUiPiGRZgGKnleeqIp1FG7CKMu0wdlynRhlrK25YJa6k9nUweAq5nE5fcIEiPgvbyEBN8CACEzJ6YxHoFWAwG@7llGD2QWqbO5XuSN0Gzy4BVNHTR7phMkjcTka48LkpYNvJCMpSgyWKLzeKBxRVS1mAcVftTjbsy6N1iA2AlIhIYg4qtldQ1k7x6cA8d2FiAFRgZoESQewssBLLFTNCeh4fLNLqqsgY0ZFBGUGWgNqPkgf73RaOiVoJ2wRr1xSwNJyZ6508PRkY3Ckh25U2vkcHer77RALXtQP7N@Cllj3LImMxkiv6AMP3jSFRhgHY9VoeX@dgxSpyQ7HihM8t9F4EiQTIqbUPBfGQAJSANGKR2PVPEBKJXTqW0oskZVSYNKJ6eZjBVXVsGBsQK@7DoD1ELsLRkGaOmBiW/ZHdBWQueTytcXNnWB7ie7LpnUPjiWrdwkV1ZWkqVkDTT7ysoTcFXQ9QRdKXA9IVeGXAinoYtipMmFoQ2KgX7N5G3DxzxRm1hsE2yVPlpDRW@USuvNtN7Ii2cBnyqoOtBsAJ3BB@BJqtUqOlVVrl1DRrVWJ577XdTOp4ZrDQUTvtKvdP4uuLBObLAGQ8dFA7aMjezdPBlUXWgFwWg1eoqbPG/kzpvnN@ft1PltMo2x1bJebUGmID1loHVdZwzNpdrYKGXyTVVtrEMj2aomc8k1RdnO9CEhXVW/2FZTOue2kjRBayvn50lgquBPw@i5hG@SLqhqwCqgAxtmsAmVpHazDem31KaaSkJcNZmGLkY1mQTOGMgEjzKNkkkMOgAB3D19EetVDi5BPTLD66MtkXG5OQGv2TXu2aZHYDKV2CGZnDa0l0ACNJftoGtjO3bGHpMBTNapE02IenMIQX7YeKBitGIwiLhjTcDCh4o79S0ZbIDRmNmF/qLTN7W3ZFvIDCSfYX3VFpozx7xd0AwvLEQwXMA57OsG1Mw4unOZnQNCENRsdnGIWp5DPGvrULfkvjxCy2DoNvKvbZHZPba8HrIXTCPsC7gd4Cra3NC4m8S1Q2ZAo90FTpsTa8SNcBCEU4zyXPcUFc2@Ojeb0FrDJh@J8rvw1B47BnRYTGj6MZT3/ti@fWW5jo1M1vYBNUhsGctgBvki9oIY1euHhb3l/F2EHDg2552P8DaKdZa5hmewrO30na7D1gAARVPTuGAf2gaQAEbbCPqH0NP/SAyqdx3oucRl0MT22kMjL7@5HpjPOkJmCV77AMqCLc50CLAkz6eHP9kHFZ8v5nJAv/@Wo0@QyQiW2Tyip8FCADG@1ke5wZL8iTnsTd2YOHmO6AaCPDkmr5i8Yw6d/CFQJWr4R4oareTcB@q5H9T2XYvyvk8mDo5FRLsJsdyDNQf1VGSHVxvIYWLGG319VsSQzhV4WL4HoPzOemNTMo2ew@RzMBEKNZZtm1dZVDgytMU9sHUzkJTpkjUVRBPjfdLIGYNZ1jb71sAaHdJoVd9G2yNsV/3QXahgIYJjyxxJosMQmiM4ohQ2FXaXw@9PsEXxJJOe7NXR3v7Fcf3seVXOjj0327daIMFt82IAlmPf9GQ2@0mwExOQifgfL/snjjOq8uK67LN7PwmM40d/sXfx4vDZSf3kG04EofGswbivIyml1RkAjH5KwX6tigzjdVxnEJjUniiI1XVkvRkboMX@pQjdwNCxGJ6N@G@i/wCHXDVD6hoGyzj8NfAUgFsIiMOwmjEcSt1UCiFpWDbwFJDbhBKHZjW35XvuoGcwKBvptUTRLQpfHklgvsnnbhG5Z4@9YSRnN/k8@V@NOh1sdgPvAnlfZlDU@6H3OnnzQd1YUj5b5oIWAgf4NggfHwxeiG8uaCFwgK/I8eEg8mJ0MyGLQANkm4QMB50X4poJWADIxfIMFOELB5qvF5ZHEwdROZUCO@lckn1jL2bTyWFIIRx0YZmrxaNFchQR1SAQ8ksH@xih6yKn5YuIJUAxuOzPx@xAS08/MdA5ouZDeM0dtDr0swCgJAYiQEnhuDpy5SscTMWxEgfsLvOawKhLRciAW5atZ0/ogZ2rRfTEu4kxYlpmZwwmSRZsXnTfA5bZ2SbITqtlLQMFviDp/nMBmDtuLWIbdPF6cyMJLMb40dgd9c22eP6X32tDAcwXT0@fkhkWOC6AbyQbnaWlJaLiC/0sLlmC@TDuWzqxgVz3oTR0HLzV@4FjMWpsT1gm09PdAVo7onBBOPEHVNAdcsYpd83@uG36z8WJEIvj4xU8tm0NKEfwRHOdul9Los@MtvD4ZPD2Hb1NWLhZaplhafNyMSfcQIvYPaDlH0CnPyjCwlkI6P2PxvwXJx7uK1driN/FXCnFhSxX1Ft5M@t4essy75ADV78ct53M8LJLmUbSNpdJO69E2IfPdPr6JXdeoHMxA3gWXavbNV3/uQzsugeWFpmI2Wt63CEqfjvHyHLR78Lp9vnvMhB/mjdwLOeT1aefzxFIEhEDag2yFucWMxE2WTOM7eutKZrKvc@XLEyQDAhQPFUjlcqtYxMWDCWHs5jD4fL42O5R/J2dxbH5rCZnySIDMstnMzO8n095FvOb99R6aLmsgd7PFNoR51Il7o8hha4FoNRvyhh93QNhGoniMK@g@OjnLgHHxshAsQpdd4h3SI4/o7BscDqMM7QMp295Q17jxMsybTo7rBeiwell@gmj4ts8f9vQPcKGPhO4FisExxjhAPESeXuAguNjszj6HREgzVnGO8O5xu9SE6PnXJn8d3Gj93EhVQ9QVZk@SYZlLIjeNu4TV5xipJ/FXLxcSNXI6C/0L7GXjuP2TNtjBS3nD2bh/I7e7/PB4rPDo@Uy7Vl9x4OOEv7exQvoEHke/10szVG2WbqdoSG7qHtxNEHUkGlihGNJYer9rtPf3O5mdfhZWuJjt4MtgHg@VPMFmiufv19z@QaSY@fFc6nKv4T/@4SBhgVdHP@POO9obxepLzFuvDyD0I3ASb3FmTvIbVNMLct7rcsKwDV61/rUf/4Wrcoy7vqtynBK5jXYfxhhZxscI5eb3L9Naht3p9Z@mE6aQ7t1XyYihXvZN0FD0@9ckbJCLv@ZMfK53MM1VKc/NsfmQo1x1Ppg4nKsO3TFw4nKiWysivGdLDAPR3cCqI@i8/ggqrH9xrc7FYzet6CS32vlLNR3Q7DJh9jfPgbHMTrmI3bt8TBWuBHenYztk7s51xv6Ndtpx4jEkM/VSNv321Ixs90z6bvMxN8fONBFdgZgM9gPKH@BlIbE@G8MMfmEmD9YONbo3om3xIKJQrBrwf6AUrUuvQwOWD5M8RSW9e0JeGcHem@2OZri7zJuL1KkLcfpf07pgD5tW2iWgbGJS/buK6U5W0fMGbNwFMPDEZFWZ9n4BW9rREcTuIed6qUFfQxZGlHj8JBSnhvzvKPVioyA3tffhBabBok81/Ddy@g9wcqd17a1rTsJ5uao0zL7On9MNjfuwrejrT/EJBr6di6NmOMoOx9XDycmEjMqaDgFZllt6Kv0zIFJr3cY@Xr7w9jzH0uBJg5@FwRrWRolXhJvaEGdt/E3NoYfsYpGjg29q5Hudk3snvRxckn4LtOz/uDzQuYeDvSueXCvcIWjFLigiHfqQufi8YoSn@M3INo9moT3/Bz70px6/nOxfTw1oDzHgzuxLarnBg6G3luxtezCMfd7zD675/TsntlzqXIEb8uqB0jkiK/FvisTQH9P9y5xBRXppLBb1/Oi3O07/f5DuIs6kWtIx1k8TruPa5/bEPWz8E71FgSIx71DetB0E5OoDV9Wd3rmGFoozxk5QzNDb8tA@zj4w38XDz0fHiU99tYy3TafPcaRQH1ktfomu7aAhA9edMpy8cBSq@/ouEjvDiMeOOM/HzJUZTjuveMgXd0ZDYf0uBj2xx790JBvprN4LLPEDojShwiDNeIT91xkza7TMnrWfSS1TH1kW5dZf0yHvy4W87gyppxbLLOH3lrfAl65Uw2FoBoNP8XH4eKKb70QWynuNEh2x647vV85xKdkg@FXPmmAjmUDMGL2bEEwNf24OsVfhXHHzIWYbFsqUWRMo@GcMXNgneSXDgfFVtIIFvTX10f3cMlwjMt77YmlA5linpaG9KzIXDP4z45i3E3Gc6HfoHeoPB93PfV@we21wa7Cn4VCUu9yAcGJJa/vXEcGnqHq67Z4LIxbeHF/6jQ7UrxzoqTE8i8u6keH9yMz@tbQ478s0yksNBXm51jnoab6krGkUxDyzsM7BgPHxRXFYElkDNf0DBwIRyXMlSPXPLbTBWWc6bMQ2IddSP/8nO4iEyXe0GV@/Mrs6rhA6YWFa5X63nzbB5hnp3cfgvhHY92zfjR2RuZCnLPTvA9B@VLvWsbzWBH4CH3uitUs/BHTlug1XxDXPcujhZ2@Y5khAZJ2tz6cHXEPNhn5YwcnX39WfD9tmuw@oc0rwTJnLy0W94Cf5Yo9Fp7mb2RK0EIoWvTsL4JlCVyKPUZlMnJcjRGcouiplKpKPBKOy3ZtAPOhaCsJLjPnu1Q81re8EcFaHdZosNWbSSlXyt@yKpNLMms2OVb80KLn/cmQ9oGc8OiNVb1ZXU1mMsnV5LldYrlkAG72PXMxuB6D7Vj04PSGLGC2zpe7odvPcZkvo/d6tEUFGuA2NOSvof9Hytxx@WJwvtPgDCeE//NftsXOHbD2PTawQB0AQ3DbmjMwe871E56uSL0@HOq48wdxgPD0@Tr0zG6dedfY4vMNO841e31wti22AYg9cvByjE1ThApeuNj1xDWAI154nJpgPZdIOIjlZ8pw@uOBDTZWe9TzNFBFtLxv7IbrdMCFYPbIRUOznWaHrG3itBut2qS@Vd9xLmn9NFLyn/@Sb36gtZtiTZ2fPG16iqSISzTztOPAMJwxUO0j@Wi6jgBRkMlQ0cc4cgFCb3J/FVc00q4MkMiMvyeBkuEbE3brpyyzz5K4/Q@XOpetjrJaP/nyTSPXrH7HBlnzv/xeVr0RjJO/yOxsenKa@SDlWxSsaHARgsPQJJNXJzJPMFjYaokG/ZqXB7BI50KGa1t9GXOcoag1tK@MtlEF0ij2siropnL2NycMaEsaCax5TZsTaEGZjQoQ93rZHlQweFUJNa911VVlzDvXmdMRK0KCuMFDBxffxEZLPXGhPUZZnbBPrIdCljFw@SG8cUb2cW/HoPrMX4exHl0tk90zW2OaIr4qaIX1KmVn9aJaqZHLNdsO7rFqvDufFHKZ88nWfjPr@Uw9P598kSv8GLjugN2/@jiLNW//1d7NqlbLffrk6VMmy7fJMl/@A2pi9eb48Hj/9Kx@9voUSuHWVz8HjjvQQ12DUkQLCntOn3avAV9cy/Q@Q/8EbwCuKGxVZxXcg6uqUnStHIEKXssZeZU7I6opFvue6Ivie2YkfB5A6LSOxXyJCtdYQzuBhQlSh@xDLoyHuBmPCSRiQxGJm4XKHmtSwCFcbbVAqRLPZFYFrmWAaw/kGVue6yfc7yGsuxfL3fx7shAEWRek1wjCeRYXsuD2HyTfQ2gxf/d8cyx355tg7sg3gAa@fpyD@uGL1yf78WggbPQk9VvdKYrVolxLY5XjHXR/BxUtrBcRcYSiKjOZIvBX0aqNcW9Nyxxdm5AtoSWNAY9MEkr0y1IomMCZKm5Xb5Y5LxSFKEBjpIzZmlnM2rEmERL9xjqC7oZnMdAGB3KA2idckwXmBG0m1/DjZwOxCnb5dfCYtLlQ3Ekvagel/RqHWcPGeuzxOrekzQqaH4/Bf6R58l2FJpsw0a7lmyzDCvDtm2Dx9wJYtcwbK7bKGSGvctrlgF7cygw0tT/o1EOgpTxivS401319iPsmBfQrsMpL7NuxQ5sDfGUSGBrXjnuJawlwzz4VraFjbmjTgT3CPZB@A0b4Dg9Oq2imcRuNFH1U5sY2tlgAFNlDvz8Bwx@ErUNKn@/G5Sx3xMZPv82kkSNPbPQKzAWPXVkejSxhIXTQ2OmDpsTciIxDYfBtIaze98A4aUM7DqbKCNtcsFI0Wo/KF6VmbCYnQCa1wHZMM1lCWK86vxEQ2tRrA9rX9zzyKsERZk9asGP53Mz@8C/@jO9SPh@B@w@Fe5J7Bm9/LN464P7nfkg@D2//MngrwNvP@Nu7LHJ0fmsmz03ARGTgm8Nj5tHgF7JooE8iuceKi0Vp2WMo1gHw@opYh@A8WyFnQjxK4w1wHooL2I7mA1oMlJ7pNhXcWFfKZtG6xhkLjVZOmhM@8kX77L4d4/5yMHKym8XNjXwWiMxc@Qhpr0wXl@pxhKpaAlUjXVnD6vuWwSqVCpM9Q@@b1c0yZ3l2VX@3Lr8PCF0FWIkb4g0GcSBKGAPCaiKasqqn8ipGxfYhmU@iqmg7vATB2lLIASAqetv@ZgMw5xzBKhAP25yMyCKZ@h0M0IM2LV83@SkDPqIMIOK4cRf0rJSHi@9wrXJE7rVoMchvEewUwUryIiFrvGPno3O7KXbDMxCYXy4QORvcf7Rgi3wgPfX5vdnK7M5qzA17emo7uEjzAKhlSiFbWM/mN9VInZIFKqAXa9AnQAl1BuqgYVofnKFX390//Oro@HRujzFBJmfBkixZq6TOM1q60QwcyRmp95n67CB7@vLZgc/KKFXh3CVChBOYs2QuSm2W0iWpv@WrHufTpoC5hPK5hyKmmYLMAc3xz2MPQ7MRwF2@2mouVUW9uW00K7VzOzGX/KdF5y4ktDUULnCde3TqQpIt0DmH/lrOMzy7x9P8Rf8FOTxVJFjoz99D7@W7hIOTgMKtwv6qUYn2AAVbgCRtyXpSyLuW5UnRPllOmE8v6Bqf1DySGiZoSHPzz1FqmMjL/KFFYsdDwKQjPkZDxx/oNnTLXcvg0B4paD6SQ3v2oQ9/GGmNjR6tOaGe55R68qAqglHftkXjZ7rrbz4JQk7NgZU58@lBxRFu/RV7XnuQt77VKuvVxoQFWybu2gGrecO@NVJwO@5EwxESyI2iYgbyFdzPOlErO02xdZj5O3xTtEn4eAz8OnaGLByd2jN91wmYKGxvDMgN7N98NR4AXIceJya2EiYYLRmIDHxM@kQ0cFusyIM2aBchda1nTtpWF1oaRU2DSvoinw@3F@u4P9ZOgh7mrPoSF@VFGfNZW6IjHNMbumbZbXOi4Oa1UhO5A/7J67dXSVWekwHaly22KbdnN2j7ykIfiVobbm6eUQg7O4EiiNednR2t50m4pQWMYUjxdOS@ACe0oUpnoA@ZMqYd7h7TGL0q54qd9kauyjI1bM@umc1SKepUw4MCwFZG0A65LNqJqOCBMEq2CuWMvp7dxsdHa8gaeU1rgpsSUdkqDqjtgrmBQ1GqBH0jiFIitNAAw18JKQKjs40U8ecqJSvRHlWAWhhMFbnbowoIvKBcs9rjcENgpAZyru7slERpxNXhDgOxqCzQGIB2gZrzbVPgr9iUAFxDJQZQu67ZtkChPP3atG2orwrIzABqJ9PHIGSumvYPTUuHB91QCglO4nOxywEIjR@As5@86Ttgz6xmyzQ2U76Fdv/9OTb8HdH0T7P/bVbLlm@U1X51mgVjTK0pq71qPrW@lkqt2mvKqo3myOPHOKRzuwrWzoUGHaMJAGVW@2oZ5Bmso@qqXV7VK8pqu1pYoxjwCl2zG4jwnZfVblb12@zqY7Am0uDj8tqprHq0Nz2naflboA9ryGo2DTJzg3u06Sg0TH7VSqWQBm31Agn4Lnt@mqJ25fw0S6NHZWHkZrsDX43EbZWgJOaOcOMMFN6lQKMXUaOLFSoXPnB4/M36orA7reuvcT0fo6lH0/Oi8hUPebhiEQoNlZNQMgo/HAAYOFGAifia1lUVlMlvfpPIbzImP9lcV5zUk2KunEoW8@VkgiWegpmaXZNd@eZ8L3PFzEyy0dGL2rfN48vj4x@r5wrbYcnE7pGc35DfsZ0Ce9hnixWWfNjv8kkk1rJSIruW@7SVzb5//x4MctaoaTWtqTYyyWZDCdOvbW2tpTe319JPkxehr6oUCuopiAo7tyxr6LXb8HV6dGahkuCfJ08oJehywj/jfiJ14fBfEET4Jj4XTi8m2PmWrq@lNgpP7TLQtoOfdZYHJ/5uwzfPikW2j5@//T/@9hd/@3P6@wV9/1pnl@wjfC47DP/J/bEdcevobnU@4rZ/sLurpBOGyWRxPXn6LiklakbiYyKfzyem9HeB7nx@EuV3ZrLgEwZn8/nCeZjLCBMww4E34z4s6hdwI@A1EzxKfC6clFhj65srT0EWTGh88FMqPY3kIitvbcuOQ149yGWROQnWPmLb1bQQjUkGPxM/AyJ9FuYpDAnfWNQrwfxoLIT5XDgp4R/BlWnonSYb1fGPnbXw72SEf28uM28u31yeGPj37BL/Xrbw7/gU/4Ye/gn8iTA7QpqDt0C@Z/18jgcvzK8G7HPgpMR31SovCybKZP6zKEDTLnzXRTCYx57AZwX@6B8@wSv@rpCP8CaQ@c/K76B0pEQj0aj@bp9mU@RFSlQqlcSPevTn4t9zG/9a3@Lfi4/49@0Z/p0Z@HenNpQS/4CfB/NjKLFEppnK3N42tHeTVLks/sG@KAdv@OEuKNHmbSZTeVdLpRpUso2aKOJKplmb8AKnX@3iXaXZ2DjaPHoK@FOVRqWiXdRqk1qm@a7WwJK4wR/Du8VHQZaza@dr6KxOKicc9Z6PG5Upwz/xecHTaxy/qO/un6ULlQxLFA7qu@nC6etniTy@FsN3Cl7H95P9@t7Ra4hw/GK/frr/5eGb/dfH4O81L2pPn6Y00BtPgfhasyElJl@kaqnqaDS6@MnFmobm5Q63MncihMx@Lha4xLuU2KtNXmczFaD9xcUO5vSEUswAW5qfGEd93jhvTL/BPynxvvJeST1JPcn1c1e5/GX@8qVzFP4fHU0gwJrkPjhurpfr5dug8FnOfJ2b5qaT3MA5yrfBacJfbgBOK9eZ5Lo5O2fn89NJDNXy/8GRM3p55AA2B2KOJrkRIs514Nk9OnoJ@DqQ9gf4s3K53ASInOSu4D/Xp/Yn/@4iB3lX8eATeMvlzs@lBpPfm9Dca/mklktqm8mk1SxuDr89v7ktbH7boA5ScafZoFNumjJLJy/OG8lmOZH1zs@z3DqSCxtymQBuby8u9upn9YuLLFagSWU19TSVeQqfai1VEY8niXat/OS8lEHB9EU0ka08Oa@tZ9C9mYJiKIBfJZv6zE@IEp61lXMpqVy/ffsWv2@vr665ixzc7/xtEIo/b7PgxV3oBR8EzS6KH3dM5oVPURrF5s0tWInnyXJS2JEKoyOl5Pz5pNBhBRn76sqOCqZ6fh07hJtFptZqm0Xw2NxWM0oO@/I8yrk8HA7PZY1GLzXaDlKt1l1Xn@KIhbIBSJSdYrV6LuvuxbncKDQxbjGzs8kcN7Ozrsqq@i5fqUAamERBBW85OZEdN8lubqN/ys1tRaGPin@qip4qCA49a6oCAGoR3iY3CqsoFQX9wAvj3dzW0ElwN@BqKGpTvb3lfspN@VZRKxxtTQXOMbDT/5H@wQr5/8//y9fMA2P/NoEdUJttFFWlNTXVjU1lO7Uj/qorwFlFXk@uY88iqScbjadr62tbG40nzTW2hl@2plTOa83Jwo@aTECF9itgNZ/A0kXFppVP5HxBhq7bEGtl@Uav5m@rN3oJe@W3ZTq2kmbnDHHGVt/psvUdPpMZ9ctv56DbxSAVGT7okpIMRKBWCYQ@EP@JWkOJYSQDTG0y9fYGKgKFQadWEfNw5@eTXE5l5VZ19Sah35YxCzK7lQWkX5UItZIs0zoY@UZe1d1Gvinfyqs3rVvs@a/lVer0FTfK5bUN7l5VlPzOZmGnUNja3NzOb22DTb2Zy2VZPr9d2NheL@5sbGxuFzdBE6pqmRJcy68JPDnAI5zb5bLp6UYZNVw5AXQoSlJlUEiJc6naMruQPHB5GK38qWKxuJItwGPyxeZ@YcJWPq3hp7EGhbld2E6tpZpPG2s7O1i2TQz5tCKVcWaOL1yRMzLXGGx7h9JN0OQ2fSo1qTGYdJp0Sko108hvFpsZNA0/TDprQEZ@az2xxqHN1WNShWt7a/Cbh//9FTyAkUlDWlOzlWNtnI10mdPprIBnT/dYCyeOPbPf9894u3bcfvvaapsrkmfCZ3Csm2PTvB6Pr83gs2t5@ocP@pA@k84Pv/zpD7/873/41c9@@NVPf/jVL379/S9@Ct@/hO/P@PNn/36niL@//v5f/i8//PmvwPOv4fuf4Psff/39v/k9/qX3v4Hv/xXx@xvxjcDxrwS4/vjX3//8L379/T//U/j@W/H909nvD//6P/D//1v8ofNXP/zrv8Ef8fLTnwGX/v6vfon/P/@rv/9Pv8T///V//vu/@ld//8f/jhx/xh3/z7/99/z3737/p3/3T//k737/@yW/P73z9/sH@H//j@DzcDofguch@fpcn@9/K3p@F26EqYAMgKT90Q//5g9AVv81f/tn8Ab/QdAfBi@xEP7yh@ELYPifFkT6o19//yd/Ebz9QRwwFgZI/hDC/jwW9oc//PL3fviL/@6HX/7ZD7/8Y9RDmY2ddD2dyd8z3AOAxQfAIeDmQ@AAkIOssBWpQE/8EZ5shVyTNam4jr3WDP@kuOenVTRI2fknqQjvqU9ZPJ2PZT@J0HPcnJuH0PUNCs2BYZ3D0CK@@qERUnCU6cnTmOnPCVn79JQBMESOABPgE06o8E99iilzjEnhKwHh8A0TWwnixzrDlffvqzUEeArB0ERSK1nBX3wBn2dVxqgPC4/aNqtKabZdxdO4ELAK7xSOTnoHXHjXRVXaY8@w74/ee8AhbG0nEzaR3rP3SC361zgoq0kQ/h14PONoCBui@k4CrxT32YPndwJ@IhE@/BdGLbrx6wfAT4pxP3hNIZKUzyaWkjgEE4NZkznLmMYtEA7jTfCfhYgEnpQEjEilo/22IIlU6CUFr6m5VAJ6ZsJSYRijNFNxVCk2h/CuwJi3NBuRLcQiKFgaOpNNP3RBin5oYj5KEBRlUCoVZxjGjGcqJaVwSfWaSHQttYYj7Wztcz@CJkpgITvu@ET5vRbmPIo3pD7ESvTyCCmCDdMmjAq3rWi@juU3NwLEqqTQGa5MpSEQcwimnPTS6z5zJkouLcvp/ObiIQYVB0wA9hunVKp@l9/YkuBJ72M8TlYcbAqyjXeEaBX4AB1S7SaDzgo6wVjblGo1MRfJ8lLtdP8MIpwdsXwhp7FGrnmzsVXYKG4UC@ubm8WtQn5jc2djs7i9nsvnNnPFQiEPVuzO9s7WrVT7MZto7Pj4RxlwTzKZbIGSqOaLW@VpFSKSl1Qju5Fbl9ObjAeWJZJ1TpbsDS4ZwjGgmwxWzEfwYdIjiT0CL/gAZpw5YWLG@vCoLOY1cd11YK7zSU45X9yRiUvnpt3miKVh9COd4YHxrwATMMhmL3CF4shhZw5fCffMNJZA7Pb4lS@7ruN5vwPMM92@5EF7Fp5zZoyCoOc6nmLiDaxRbwnE6@EAt46Y7j8ahv1BCwjEUWsO8Ax@3L7jLALYYq@Pl@TyZbBjCedDacsSgJ8cfvn8LPI826/vPpc22bOjV3szj6IAKrIX@wdnwesWD/WjFgMU3@y/eDH7Kh7YxVlhxa10WtM0@MFnmj701Fbf@SB5bbmpIW/mCltyPn0xNaEDc5PJ3HatlpnfhG7uhvw4Ad0rPG74lB@oPLLbbNIhod/Z7Dve2nY@mTR06SWuDtvJ810Elocr6wHZtU07Ilp4W8N4uNwTHuiFTtfq9kCnXDsBANSpC9bSdfx@7geQmNHP6G6PEU@D/OZC@vPg0nPo9w3w2F3cFTySroOxsLf@wFcwAMYr6VscGiAO@TPt3kh38WKxM9RrdKUHw62YLTxEmzZSoa1AmxHpyGsTtNyOJOH8otVhOUlDzVMo7GwXt3fWC9vp7Z3tjSL0YovpfCEN3fStnVw6n8tv56FzvpNPb2/srG@AjoPQ4s6WlABlYnWyWVDveVmmp2UbeExiBc@bdLReTUq0zQ4KP5sobZUl2oHHeJvJ69vnOQYRZQkXsK5NqnJhA1eXr@dZXpZknRkscXCwmzs4kOVn@ILjpbs5WW7jS3E7l9t6JssmheyCHi5ApB6@7W/iwKosW/iyWz84QAwf8KWwjThk@ZKH8Je@/7IFYDa@rK8jAibL3wbocoDc4RRtU6wRf8nlnu3K8piTtw1/AFfnbxtE7D6@YABGOuAhuxAmy1/6kcDGluUTDieSeu7nt16X5UP@Uq8jiq8o80Weqa/xpU4fiOTCG9QDWe6Co@uapi3LLXBibZBlA1zGVAe/AbjwyAV7pMvylOcDcyLLE4LWjUtZvvD9IR2g5/lzvTdqm13@mbr8aUDQIQRZk/H@QevLL1vdbsud1ve/PKGgr756rn@Yjt1WtyUiti7g42AsCLocTGc/JgZdXOj9xUFfQ5A9E3QxvTCJwgv9W6BMfLqY0ODiKwz6CoIWDdQJhPAZAHALP88G8Hymt3iQ/6Egek5aLbmMIotVp6OQ4OpperTIErlhuLTIU/QnpANLqP@cDpgv4201U3wy3pY3t@TSGjzlJ/I6OKFqsFwyx5icPJdltbHTfCJvFeVS8smTTPJx/gmTt3bkkry1BU24Wr5F9amoNx1lkp5Uc@CRzVawQmMVhCdYFcIkODMnI@25iWtajEzmbexTqbwFONxuiXviXo0H0AW5Jh2CC@P9RcwX1WegMHJlG/fCmvi6OklMpFpbH@nQZXp2My6VBOxtuVttIIJP@FPJyG9rb@Umi6Zb3MoBVa9to7BVqTSuPzXBNKrmy9OEXs0XtssTfG5tRI2i1b7ujVbzW4VSY7zayOSbKyu5T92K/JMaob6FzMZHRbe2y@Dns4LruEBLQQzc2wDfTEbC8GFVlI3MFLzDAKf9aGWNkkxuFZJJNVmGuCsycF0wnWYGsXD9spFBO0LZ7BQgumuOxtDW58q3cym7lyXS1LjvDFMoMXkTLDLwxm0hiz5PoZ@fLq21ipXaP5n7/Df/ZNFnsS9@JG5ibualxK3UxqMdN3akxI10e3Nbqfkpfs2mUz3l96XZY8a6qVVpNYlZT67HO4/1ar17UvcHhuu7UiKz7mw4idXVVSlROavJ6/KRdhFMGtWyNC95jtOWOLOnnV9UVlK/1YxSRqs95dPLNTDWWVZyTdwC18Yb9/jEznYRi6LLvETqt/xAIlIVcEplHFuXE6gpjL4zxhUWlXOeocp3CZr4Ycc3nbFNS01LL9EAV/QSt3YaTaiu372y@jfb65karZBSQMZub0kujCNaAyElbEc4gZHQIRpBpVXAXi/KoldjsuHpzrutd9vvXr4@en10wJ7mStulbeT7OUhJOp/MJ6EQn0KTbJ3sS4nhJ6eY/87@qpwoDZPrG8n1SLGdVxO@jCso@koD99U01pvNBggb0gvv1WrhSb64ndoo5beYmqjhTsXCFrIbXaAOMuuJZoIj2dhSwU1j84V8opYV3vmtvJrwMvwNohQTnpTYfvkex3L8m@GsArmytHFj9bZyC/@1W9aoVG6pT3YrHPhze8vD4Z/yEbzxR/iJAEZhwvDfTui0i0Tzu0yF/1fwZ/eI51TeLMpq4n21BqLw7uLdRUJK7DC5QKWXyorOFdSkLlp8azb9md6a927NWws91sBKXQve4LWyxoq1PGPmWjabPVd/VAAbbWdnc3szIf0GOHbHwnIIDVZadkzo9IBqX7DUsu5aL3VchmoHyy3B8XL8EW8Beerf/@ebcwztOVxLjAZd1E/YeBEvujYz7jf1srgbDH0lCV0WXRvLOiSCqL9HtIGJreGZMrhlXZVupEeAa2yMaCMZ/JQl6RHuHsRXxYdLs8feSMWBuZwqPXokFLA30rzRBSLHSMIzky9LtxKyR2@3PUb38OD8Ld/nruNWKGfIT1/rTxmP5NFVKdw2pS3qmG6E4DXW4VRAbtYYpUiUY@Z48o84WGvcQVIODl/sQxzoo3do0aOILbstvKWKsrfSUVnQjgAP8KqWquAUgSMgoANPbnqoA9xMb1B1ZimWx/AOLZ4EqDTLp4mSNOuIiA18bUJ0RN8BreYBYp66wnPA1i5EsiIPgh7KBLAQc0fNIV2i4naNtCg9PMG80VTZjb8BUcFQVmEFNbIJk3BBYfCbZSmiMWiLG3eqIZsJW76ZhqIt852WSgAnfEJG3Upro/SgzItqWJa@VgywkBxXKX83ePzYeDdsDJpldVAd4TOVGkATfalYHGRtVB1UQTyGDatZHjVSKatZHahfK/iOF1they7sPE8VeYOc21WgBRejemr6Y8POfGc30wcNOwUkj9NrP6l@TOvVHFpoaauaT/fT34Kpw/MBaY6qH1N2Wa/AFxcQxzbBglWS0ssxL4xyqfSrHxt6E02@PkRMpQ4gM0Cn1@inUk0VEu9D4HzEcv/xYz3Vr03K/UxGRah3608OGiNwNFNVfC8pemXy5GNjDPFLCjyrkExfBeIhnuD1bUA70FcGHvMyDUnnNJJFOgHyBtXq2k@erP1krbqy8rExyQyaac7@Ui6UBiR@gsSXI9uMlbWfqGyGJTRDrchfWKUvtDXcK2qlUsDk9DASk1O49hMIGaZSPtW3qC/Pol1mlDCxL5HvAqW7EWivCXWRqbPML@VBdVH3DMsS4Py0iKGFZx/guUJpus1KJwgMExfwYuD55MkTyU9abIWDlFG5QOdcxxELuoYRdxbTORqMH6F0n35dpIZ9nRv0relmJejFr29GqiupJqpwnms0EATVwE3utsw1Ft8ACcqGtAfAkPZAuAxqEWSS0BMCsioCobT8AoJYqCc6/PgvOgEJ9RPa1kHNBxXCyYDKvIAMK/2hSroJ5MkCF7MqlB44oKpIjyATSAPmwWqyGigy9vgxE6@VKssXtrAtQDCE@5DKI9AcpZD4AygFHEjlB5BR1IeUCND2CENwTUYsoY3fLSFxcoQCEVIf0vwACY0OkFDGtscPXEG@qZwMLItHjz6kqhuCIPinrgnEh7Db3yREc19iu0cvj1@f7Z@8rJ/CL3RKt6MX1vmXwc5dBTnEKx5blk2bVA39JG9@85XBmIKdMrzoAO96brOvXr9ghcKrvTQePwysT/CxdmhQSwEm06NrYDzNcbvZa@vSysYvrcdreWk/rFeiW1jFAmGTznCg652DY2DCU2A8HC6ExlycmRq79Wtgep644TLj3xZOB9bRgTgDPNcFaqG4EZO2GsV29uOKjDTt@HKtrkVXQPc4glh8uhlrxKNT/ZDwJkvqHINESzvbuVyJ5dLoyPuOgu9Y9x0bvqPoOzZ9x5bv2PYdO8KR9zHnOWboQK@vb4bOrdC5HTp3AudGLnSGGDYKoXM9dG6EzmLoDFPbCFLb3Ca8LOFzk6qu6WJYfmPbD6NxhxF5FgFNftZzAwgtzEFC9I05T0hvO@65tZMTCR1mjxCoUNgM30H7@LBVhVOV5nSkecr8TXhCWyXxbh4J7L7rglban@DVvSB0aonhAQ6ShEecGX1TB2PAHIGVUj0A@TfVErVBI3daCk@vQAzVfPAO0fHeNIiTp9unufgsCC4sCubYCgux8fO0WMCYyDkegkhOZSnW0nKMGzG/KNYVVLDI0SUQBQ6BZRA/9sNP88wdL0xy/e4kYwgXJjlHFMdbXBQLeaMQ8qofldp/wlb10@N2ikmlDWYAxoRCJxmYKVA8/6t6ky/Jv/7@T/839uvvf/4r9sOf/@r//Y//I7r/A/7873i@RSEA@NnPGS0tgZ9/xWghCS1qCSMR/HpJ/uFPfwmv/8O/Yz/89Oc86E/@Qk5vBIggBL3CmL/4Z/jzB/jzf8rpYgD4iz/igBhFTt9KMdNKAaif/TVjkBpiCZD96V8yJqfAwFCE5DV4HW9GzvrhCAI2NMjVnA3nv3hjK/A4p6ZkwCve8uFbCgtAjSB3dQsPQAvqHpgzfGwTtbShGz08NkN4OR7aPwaaMI6ndUHerttg9IghiSTk/vdZiSVTCIMDK3jcWZXrcJF/kW85DEXYlJwF6vDOQ4GK7rMNKIHurQTyTT2Bqadht4V6pHkuI4K/r0xoJvwGRPYli673lERafmwckhFXndN9r35XF4UWmyF@XBhdcyqJcx3ykQRj6mam2CCVWR/oMoYH/kSjkoc5GOKBNdWQ38hYfCEupGfRhSUnqs3@0cFMhcFPC0zMy6hGChKqMlm@BxY5LeBVtLjW4/CcXgHQyJXWm7GjgxYByz/@8Y9lKeKXQxly2wphiGSKq4wgKB8PKkSCCpEgqyNwkq4pFgozNFDDgXoxfoAWjxZRUfFooXBhzfHLAcmAviAfEE13@mOvV51HTRo5ruzmkUdQ5ptVUU/ObdI5NSarcxEAZzxOdbYsF6POzcHMF9TimMjtmE@stJZjisWJVArinjTLpaDk8juLSi6e4B2o883UAxMq5H7HhDIPTGizeH9Cs8WKcWPol/P3frXjq4lAw4fIeMVPxBoobBr/FEQvVEdIsUtORYUuT110eVrXDlMW3GkP/ln/voHYRfZu5BYC7MTgSVB8eODp0IEuh4NWsN9V0m32WoDHuh38puGu7bimFz2TSVw@bCfxqCzD6drQqqXx3gPr0hRXUJviyNN4uxK0bMIKxZOloeuDqDmj0PK8uLBsa3RxAcZnv6OGDMRXzcCjBJKSARHBFYmvBKbt0VBx8P6WkXo/TrJ3ebQzy7hUjoYiMAmJ1Bl06AyzD50v1sP7uv3LlzGL/AZvsEhbI4XOWO45A6dr2g6eEoaxZ9AfhriRIH04JFrSTE8zI0KR6EQrRlpXRdSvPzsq@7qAN8778QtxBDFmpJk7y2PkrLsguYulyfFofnqnn0/vaZTe07vp7ViuN5qlmTxxtAefn5f0uhJiAMCQjPX7yUiL0znnyImREnh7aBdRhAeT2KZlVW2ktA6gdQGudUA@0sGbR4cGCMLfLOP/3QXoR99/aPGRMXs6BX0zoKvdqYvm@bPwCoAfqmq4VDKSXCDaew9MS3R0qIeXZjIpLhtPpICKORyadni3to/4HpnHhVVzck@rrao8cAFN7lWaXRaWF9HeRdvs61OzrQjIdASvn@MTU2@TvnpYxlHRkdKDPgANZObS@ZgpRicHEVBpicjo6StVXS5WHMQKpIcm44jCw@X8o4G7WdWMg6BVPgfiuKBBE3TsLZ1SPJwOp/y0sT4dA@jrUd7@8JJ85YhzBu9kCPCB3xmfT4fJqnepzxMlyNIDWoQAVotnmc7s8JstB6zxuTL8PBbdn1MaZQgiVf1Sjlkny0rcuqvEI1LhyyS3Sh4mkvcJ3YNlLiJqHFmownY/rwmZw7yr9/uGoUQxcp87S8yx53QC@mGJOfaSVuVigUINYpKmG@G9tFVuX6iSBc5DeF7B8w08ESH0QS@4QPl5Q7vWH/KikIE@jFgtwqdhoC0a4aIanUeMQEm@Gwdyb4M0jaVpGnNpGrE0gxoQTzICJBmxJEUpYPHcVQR9szNaop0xCHvu8LhLbcPHdnQX515vklayZKVZ8ipZAoWcNJOlfQWUcrKdLO2Rw0uWTslxmSx9DY6wbiU/JUt@tUAAF17J8RT9hQrHdyNZ2lXUW2mEZ3776WrJUlCmAPOEvxJHbvnwakvM@jvBqKppprlRmWYoMR48HMxWo5mmbw7@@Zm@/BB6CFypssIaAWMHJNZoRFoMng40G1rfuTZdZVHzUfKHpsT4RjiGAuGpamRQBaVkTPoomUjGlREnDENp8BGeQCDqzdJiilh@rmd2HzkidZBQKuR4@sQ9jeyBtkLhDQCODuL0w/h@ecVR8AJ8GJ0YeRmdc@T4yRFFuBhAXUAWMvV98o5MYVnPHEvOSz9aQvNjBFiIGR@ElxKhjeh0sOHQNqXEhs4wLiQUirN9VjQOfkSlROmdiUZaQdTMJcHkLXKGiiFa@dW7shOJh6TFVBAGNnJNXsuCdoF0MQaFui5iqfLKByREdE6bjmM0UWz3hJPguLpJU1uxrBny4/IkSXPF1SRE1vDshbE@4qmH8zJ4IsPndV/9mBO82UVBBJGYQSpcvzqfYb873H73DWqfCTMJLDKsFzel8@b1na3sDOX9MNn5AsTANNtTFxpHQQohy6F3ELHM75K1ORN/bPtGPk80wD5j7ftsC/oE9/Bttm/BcaGV4F7FPS9xYPaysJxR8xZJ/0rzjRYNUxJ4eMYDSsOs3U0rz/iiIsYQbKPh8dkF7MYLOFp4iI8y4M6wnNdyd2zT8qqwbtOheuHMBZ91cHCVWHCQfsQT1D2tXwuWaIHH0cXJ3tGrF99Ao7u1taXOT0VgrYW4YTsu3TlNEHRbCmk8jha35NHaiZ7jjlbObXl@SRl5gDGg07wNFz9Rx1WhyyL6fKbuQjwOG@GowHUZVgM9ppXQ1NGxybYEX/l9mMqaLpD45i3wO029NZw1QunACZ2LC2q@Li5wcc7FhWjFsGiCaaTfJJg4ilFKxNcwkZ3lzZ30iN3@8YB2WvnDbuIMR776JAF4Dkd@7CDW2B5Z/hIHHBWiLZj@DL6ynscxicNO4EN04FIMpbCBHddCEQ@w4bEQGoc7aUGlSGeFmzd4O483dGw6jJ4O@CVjHe8K8vwBVyJ7bF/rtPiDp0Ln7kQo4suw/Nkwx@YX53g8Lu71pIFjnzdpZnY1mucp7EBH49Ia8jPKgwUfnkqRiGBamQU8bvXNAZB0ChK7YAz5pQVC0zuwul0Qn6y42pUvaznTIWrG6WR2/bM3E@yN3reCy0jESjC6VEiM/gI7ldjhqR4rbIINtZMGzoZfYCwujmF4QGqOlmYRFHy34LHFndvpSNwVZarOP9fzK8oFlijfWG@5eH3rlW5H@EufT9GBaDFFSbU@Mk8JzLXFuYtJPHgxOLdTEgc4V2maUsMlakNFTsj@gZ7olIauieo6k@frJ/S@4Z80quAZtyXpkU0aCJeCMYMvsgFL10brjebZ1GBtqs2@YOsFiW5YcmiUmRMAOPgUXww7hEFUzAdf5ic0jfxFW/4CZxWlRwlUilz8ML4v3eim43lC8WYrAh2udxVTmLxa@C/FyAvWDn4nEmQdeyObQOECSlYUOQVoU7Iqc9RB/NnoYprkEVfR85jSOFP3SLAasPzms9dvm65rE5h05YAgDxw81ZavPS7fsRqYlgPjmsPYYmAkOrq6syMWvfFrMNPya1y2VeKJUIOj4SnPqO/Lswo/k/fXeNIDF1ezNdoB3Ym1TrKLkQMyViz7LgKoGSJBRzVFa8a@8ErwBRrSPkpgEy1zUIg36r20EUdw8TWeppFrliPtkJKPUoMEdjzQRx3gZ1qma1EeQ0Rql6GRVBfZWrlyLD4Q5w1tWv4tZzSZooqlyogpjoKXJvoHC2YlWiXv67077q3Qs/nt3OYOLbpmdnqUHjR2muk1oyozc2Tp9sAbu9fty67TuwILgw0/tCbG9OO3jBU3GO5KKTzmJwbkN6tZOhRgi07V2MnRjhD/TA86d@JcZow2IeMJIUnGgl1K5RU8KgA@afwpyeU5KWVrA18K@crrQWOzWbWrufKgYTfLdiqljlLVUSqfUtDjcV4tg6LmYzWNUZOWUmbX2Et/vSOe6owDsk6HHTu20XOSHqPLtKMTgbT5zK9AA30YrU9X0FVx3KhPB@VJH8Qq4rwX3UM5E9NyfLjRdGiiGg2WivYdkF/8eTTe3CjPh2MOHz3Cdc1lYdBGM3AjDcetvmWAeiJ@ol2CaxxLJbFS32Aot6C70M/inpwWaMAUDC77oYYznIrIFge58PNSiaCsKdj0qemHQPpQLZDJC7yDwwUwDsLZGwNngJpaMJVThe4Xph20Tri5Qi3j0nO24of52zAQHuWGNkNcgM1IWyfgUWEClBYmM1UsAybfhoUrEci@qyV50KMP48GQzAON0ys4glffXQx1yw1iat4Yr/9UWB6ZYflEYwmg4xY3812BNRotGr8scDSCZsQxP4jvmE6JB4INHe8kBt2IM0KIr@1QnEf8UkYFGkw@2sXJEHEpG6ooamAcnvmWHCZLjAYnyuBFzU85EvoBQjGvS4IHEDzQR70lwT3EPfaWBbsQjFc1Lgm2IJgvVFkc7kA4N8SWAIxw6A3E9WLkXIx0q6/wVda4PvuWK2yFpVI@YwMRYLxgeHnE4zOxXp2t8NLhwhYTL6ifJFYcAEVaEZUH30NpoVA8GUThchFJk/OE3bB7ExMjVsDiC0oJ1C6mr67F8LMIAVD/QJWy@XA/cV7aQUZj8qPx67oguAI6/9OnuygTghiXv3zTlz5eQjg4Gskh51aIh5@UGJYrj/RRRFocR6znj2o333IN8@FXykKoQnjdCut1xwLbEqKqaOWE3tgPVdmT0KfhNVkp0B4hH3m1uJ@PhTnpwW4q1cg0a4VO4@Fc1VHuIaYOLXIrVBa4eUsvz7HTC6AzcegaQAfcnJEzIyYzopZ@bmYflpsE0EeVmnhT5orWANOwJghcQJ7OyzWqEziy1WSJ@@MlYVYcmbUEGd/keAEIRhWgAVs2X437baJla3yhEOj5XGEjTeP@HOQ2ZJOvrB7Cp3@AyoWME032GO9NiasktoA1c@BBvpFftdkqN5M9rukXZ67BV5olnySRRjYvTyR1T6CVLLEcC3bTlNnt/Xrot@PMTVh8MXvHU5brCr/QfUl8iAjeLmH0vUIWz0KhyWIcRxJIM9zTJNHO0MWNUjjfceH7@GNhvG4vtcCQqnI8HGnmCP0AMJSjsdLC5qqFqlNsib0Y@cZNOrTC8LoyLhVgspelqDrH7twBNd5R32A/D3EkGoLLC9HCdH3KrI5v24IZ7MfTjAssZs5k5CfU6a7jtBXfYBIGA2Hwl00DUJrvMQrMKm5ehslDcsLoZV2x9Npvd8vgsyK8qF0BDzQ@hWwiEWtdqjZlrDYR@8by6DY9CsfWCJLyp4RwLIlrH1aa9UfowAR6tDCSr/FxoxhtJxZ6nlrimHqQd3Ubx@3o3DLqWldk9A8KAmFq0NEONx1TGdwuGGXgG6vFluObaNfFKlsa2sRBoYteO3TTA2oqFRmTCU/s@E1iJTv23GzLsrOmfQVGdWsqJYLhrRLeWJrZxtFbvHdUaBMaLKcBIRATKClMTbPNayW4xxTHHiS@UZAGkPISHitBg/l986oNVj9fRj90vAn9TqGzkNPGw5FDISIh2lDIPlmfwk3uOZraFT0GQU6F8IQwCk76cN8pH7fK5LmBlMcjM9QIigbGJIUrn8sylh8SKob9Gk3J00zd6CERKHufeHcKiosk@Vby/KLHDXDICpxRBGefL/0d0jgeJkHWiTeld8g@vufRwX1oJBLlXvRTJBqvxRC8WByFHIflMH4FGMAZ/@j0bG//5EQTpzXzaQSceuDDzLhug3YRihvKxSgrTiHgHk5eKI8ws4ibp1cNkZP@JR5hsoJNWBWukZ2cV7hJlOcgk6e3uWwE8CoHJ5bQHLR485CXObHUegh2FPIujKZEomX8aD5whBWP7uWGbhi4OvelOXCA4l2z3weiOS8ehexAJ3LETz8VpO81MM1mQDwPz8yFZ2LhGg/nRIVQmtFzQ6BSFEhO3IRwt0wOwdJzaVUZZPrwFW350Rw3Qnf5LlhPg06aFQLXgqLkUhkEVGIBmUjIuwWlz0NWYnECAQ/CGzxcyHdBlHxAZQz2aTx9fEqigExaGCvWkcxIqWZb/Sd8@DEIIQ3LcK8Lj47lTWLHK6UYEBHqJANqAi@bx2pbq4ZYUnlf41CdkWuVp7ImhqSeKLNk8AHvuYq1oI5EuERppohxE2pJIB0KXomgIJwoaMyvuTU/8lREnkbQItSKn6zkb9@OV3DI2mwVr@IQ@if88St7nDgfLrE48BGnfMIzzyfC4gwipbsiL2ZTXJuM3LHJPUWm7mhFwrSnsxgXK4lXDvZAjR5qiiBNk0/XdZyx3V4J9ERUUfiaYo7vQYjgdAiQ98V3WRFi4K30m@ya9KU@AKuwb05YHW1qnQ5akmJzoXgDuYeHl@FRm8wbD4d9S2y2Y9c02yaOISoUcWIoxBgxGjTpEFftcPg0usTcJUTS2BFivrb4Td8iwBt3u/zaZob3QoJqxcvYrZEm1e0pv1Ea96YV@IykuAseFXAfun0RInjJ8doT3NKtSf4JPDyrHV6/xRXjOCuH10VDk1aSpB@NLeNy90tWyOW28rn1fIRl/lB1TlvfoIupfRPJDyjk8rlcMb8hSbvOcMrXmyiGirg2MogwzV5gQ/8GZBOvUbdNqQ4tBgHiKZ2e6V6ZbU2STsw2jQG3xsQRFGW6GN32N9@jD9hWeAgRXm3upfn95SBh@MT2mR8oYNBq57SEU7xD0x1YIz4R7FxZeON6MK3dcfp955oGonFGmfMDIw3METBlTWVxkuiwAEEL2S60hx@4oYvrpfWWc0WHewg2gJ1q4ZlIND8r4c5WxBBNjN9NG6EE0jP6ujVAcVpAAG59CTngEwBZa48N804aJCLiM2nw781uO8YYj0vQ/ZLJgvZzqK5AdTddC7RvyGAqFYoWoR0K@Oz54Sk7PTo4e1s/2WfgPj45enO4t7/Hnn3Dzp7vs92j42/oLFr2/OgFaJdTVn@1B76vzk4On70@OwIPuX4KMWUKkOqvvmH7Pz4@2T89ZUcn7PDl8YtDwAboT@qvzg73T9Ps8NXui9fQWH@ZZoCBvTo6Yy8OXx6eAdjZUZpS9aNJYTx2dMBe7p/sPofX@rPDF4dn31CKB4dnrzCxA0itzo7rJ2eHu69f1E/Y8euT46PTfYYZk/YOT3df1A9f7u9pkD6kyfbf7L86Y6fP6y9ezGT06O2r/RMkPpbLZ/tAZf3Zi31KifK5d3iyv3uGGQpdu8A8IPBFmp0e7@8eomP/x/uQnfrJN2mB9HT/R68BCALZXv1l/UvInKTcwxUol93XJ/svkWjgxOnrZ6dnh2evz/bZl0dHe8Tr0/2TN4e7@6dlJr04OiWGvT7dTzO8rYaSBhzALQgH97PXp4fEt8NXZ9BmvD4@Ozx6pUIhvwXGAJV1iLpHDD56xXMLTDo6@QaxIh@oANLs7fN98D9BnhK36siFU@Da7lkUDBIEJp5Fs8le7X/54vDL/Ve7@xh8hGjeHp7uq1Bgh6cIADgx3bd1SPQ15RrLCejiThBWyZfcNBUnOzxg9b03h0i5gAYJOD0U0kJs230ueK7habkLp9zunMCbn@UTQyF3n9yze7S3DxYfP8xPDv1fQ6OzHZ@8i4VBQxMEwquYBaW26qJttsbdC8vuONg1D6LxGeyB103jkZgqXhh0Lt11Ix6fKKcIicTFxZv6BfRzTy8u1PRDYsbIuC@G2Bp/F5Qq8th39DZ182NjS1FG1R6LA3jS/DSM6FjL42DwQWXZbNsU0XAhCSL2h4nESVGArI2akVaY6DaLJElTzPGxIjrGbHawyJ/edDz4sT@FL7xtiHiAcubrFrJZ7MMSGXgcHQvoh0TopDZxXButA7A6lKTmmeZlV8lFk8MuvxigUv04BDuCbmBXUe@J3jK7M9Ezs/GJWFwBRMaKf0aPf3YOv9Ab3wTLmCgXzaWcKXxojx6qTw0lBEahypOi5UVi9YnymEfHTd98rFAtB@e70BltL@s/PnyLnblcYaM84/888Od1C5cC4oGD0N41KF6THs@bHAAqmIXdL2CJNeVTqtlsJA5YZWRPBsB4gFAPga6tNrSp2FT3TGrW8dgifoZDND40xq41iVIPavjLk/rLZ68PDkBzIrUb28WtzbIkjkFyRz9O8@c3mA6d3ovcBSv62gIzjYIitWQX7J6DuRMMI0cuYukhIJ6b7hcaeeKF5sF2Zm4j8EPP@DAQZtfDY59sPPlMxpObXJnhoklzRfLldWHNFAKgxLKqYm4G@oQsfB1MJZIBg29d7k@p1Cb4g7iD6u9X8SBDQoCEiJmD4WgKkgudC9J78oG/CpT6NrTEC0E02Zfjoe6vQeKMQZ1JS2NxiSS9CdmOlCLYtVjQWF@p2CkmELEyS4V/ch6dgwlJHDueX4O5pwU@PxbyBs5vxImNGITnb9VHp8DGgyBmxj9RkY85i4ohMDdrVSiix4@DlCoMB1JVQRQf/4@f5xetDUQKX9DAZhD7K48CPgchNAj9NKmyGy6peNQK4ikLiRXvILmLsiOwlP1zasS7f6wf47jCU/7I6zpIQ/JBvvFBAnbG2PQ78YPw/1fkyQL8FehwAvaQW6SHLXtsPpCThJXzCnqvxBTr2l8xFlmmFnIz6vVNiOY2WjC9IGNiGd6ETywBC0TpTH2Pb/g5r8oCBqCQ47hGtP7iqQpUiXs69JyeUt19xGf6XdsYDBX/lFS/qZjD20yTzZX2l8jhi8qn8HMsktwLPPTuKW2@JZ2BHS7QYq0p@8KTOY5UnnQOZjq7RoMeQS0n0UQ25P0aHopTTlQtv/JPxAqjsJVp@6G3YIouP4E1mA7Bgx5jCt@fAfEVCK19imZYsA3SrCGhC/ONy@9plJ@JVhyPLgcVSO0yO6PV057eoT4zNkViqTOuqcYkEc8XbXGQZsscXWNz0efYaYl3iI0pX9Aqc0xEjEUGZoSvfFUNuE6N7HVAPQ1TorwG1L@2L228MsTkQ1w@hBY7ljO6L15jL3U6obP/sHzLYeIpZGstnv6hTcveDT5fiUNz1HOHVLCn/4UXcgQszmu0LqEdCrmkG5foKfsyal1nrAk8KK2MyLl/0CT0GegY4UVG/@3SDgHKyswaWCaf28EgUok3ZNUvfPMFXbzuBq5v0CXGmauQKSAOfHDBrDCDkGS0m3CR5nxtI/qCvQ4FKUGLT0tgOV1fay19PNDtjj6w@lNadfrB6dlZzx57Q204xdtP46OBdAUKwAHtI5O9tey2c@2xZ1AdcCDp9NXr0@P4wF9k5GuXj3wx9hWkwZ5RytIc@g5uZPGczgiKxiyzqbhhyg2He2icUIy00LDWFD1wt5BLAgTpDgLL@MtXr9mXpm26YA8e05pL9sIyTBvUBxhTtArT63FNg@AHmPqpSJ0doO1CIztlZlo0qBOM7UkiAYEtjaKlQFUEgl1x1jWOzU9B1CNjgtp8hsN8tf1BpZ4zFJs1cNAUjU0@xNkZ99MSHqj99vDsOXbGececxmagWfPH@nAskZtOAz5YC5lxdXs0BaZIs4M3QPZ9Yzcao70agFFazk7q1A3wpqE2Dvv1PcgqXg8mtAC1IFBVTesKT/ClYbiHlBGtsxXDZiHfymLTa1pcuyNUR6z0pLD00niQu5ZmxR12ZqLssuO@bkAPi52OMfr6OtiBzxxvhKAv64zlCvl8PpNfxyHa16d1jSoCfv1jXSXp8OXx0ckZMFKcW@QLRtBmIvPpJFW@GgvYkcHzVCH371Eh@/CgMQvviXlogvuHK8hlPmMhl2Qoe0PH4V7IoRc3h2lIFofkHZdOc8XNOiBCseoIqXrXqHz51AilFMGepvNkxYmwvGkJ6KQtlhThPdLWB7nq43zoe4pMfqAAzAn5QSyXegZtcRYRlMnAHATUWyO/ddc5gDR7EG3AMD6WCsKRTCfRSgLuqVE8bRPXSHh4pNPAuzJc0C36FYgcLmHxdyyBzJBuUoPc6C2rb0EdALqMnoMNDldXfkHQEET0mFqJSjw4ABEbJKJlwRFSULvaziAA5VRJUrBDT/gPvanhsEQXutnY0/KGptmm46vGQ34@E4ZrUMv70HLwvXul8OAmKZGjdZMuKBs8Jw9037iPG/pxA2aLl7nk5wakyt/zedbDbj1HBDk6HVElxWN0lQU97DTDeV6Vih1vy8a4KjJiye5LQDFM46QUUAXlTQJBLhKXNF2UReU9uzkTI9IJkd4wHoC4@KyuGQ/w0WPehXMOgAtpNSBgZt@nTwzfs8TdsTGw@AvmF9ed4p42hecRMjdVA2YeWHiuOR8bcFjXwV8E1nyO8TlCk@YI53aT4l2gecA3C5mfhwSo4FS3CGRhAc7MQpzri3FmBE4xWXloX9F@OoxFYsFzwY/ocEA/IiPC7H/p@KqXdv31HT7BFOS@23daeJgmaApIDR/TdFiwUW/qgcUYHQ3lOzvjh4BW/CwJ0sXeJt92YRWoH2aNVfwRi9q5zQtKBFR5XaLtY4zaLqpO5MQfUaPIKcdOFEWrY@ZIUSSP@4LuRrSyQCl85BILayauxInCi5TjUQaxKPmZKIK4eJRWLEpBCrePz5QuxkDVj894zny7hFYlUQmwalBAOWmgT3jvJkebAWmYBs/xjm1cLDSFgCBgw2DB/kIEb0rhuRmxaXuehv9KS/Boxbe8KtM5pLn4IVQTf@keqQGCioVP6WwWWxEZUgUb6CU4k0P1iRH5qlAUO6KpggzzACmWbRf3ainRVNQSSwx1PmuIUB42bNGkG8QDnKWX4W@NKSKBTJRYDoRnHQhVCIyn8zAa0JXlxeLrwZwUtsz0FlFwUIIS19@0ZIw3A4oSq1e@5g5wcuec7gZU6M/RUUoS35TtgV3HfbFFiaiGUzT48Gx5YeSZE@ie0RwzoaD2JxixFp78oIlAewjiG2HKTb/ViOdiKfRsU7IIJtKqBFy4C9hndsCnpcDLWxtiHY4hoL7j4BHWvcBBYsE6vwlOepxlZKVYI9qL7hgW11BxtkWULo@bXqCA40XuE5eeyZUUOV9G5HC2GZFiLWdMSJTIG96dw77gpwtzRKoUi4X8X1bguNwxWrGXwuU5nCj2ZRIR4PLL/S6xCID9cr9LLDhwpNjvFgv/gOmAtRR/Vi5iJcFZgIsSRY@BxpSiOsgPmEShJjNQRNC0GT1gxuwrC6iNaFUx1inNmUoBi8R5cvE06DHhBSOuLIuLIzCvEZRGM8wttHHGpdkOjskQuQ@6SDU53iTw0pw9HQoz7adAZdRU8R6TIAJobD4IJvrMA752k44ZSvIOC/VB8SjVbi@@uzeG1m9Vcuq8QekfqRQSX1lIfGb@aKuwi1Wav7QnWF0mqMYFT47bRmhZWjDjK91DVSpCVTx3kRKKs3gJpsyDMGUegCkbwSQq9jq0l@RMuHh4sHkfivPzeRz0eAcdKYEDNG3bwkFs7Adf69P7cK6AsZWgNXU6X1UWRAjt5PtwPJnFQYe194LZOOHZ03HU7aPpOrNHpS3lbFxWFlAUUJWYJyuNZJHWpv6ugPNNJerbapetnhX0BBL3lzQ/U0JExqXEvWASKBE/6ihAFtb//BL@pSPFGq8PnPDYMAxYy9JnVgcNGcFHmPhWsSBCRJHF@6EiIM6Iu0NnlR/1VmdPmsBT6JdGU@/NyVM@4BMZdMpD1rjGikmc34ULlZPfWvn6bVH37N70EwvTHzpDsHE6Cwkg@AGO4/NBqRmVHpqmM13rB7VlC9uz@XxF7baZA@MeXskfz2W9AFnHjelQqW3zWrT@d2EWefFL4Lew5Bu@jCwh8ouFROJEuy4Gt5g9HrRMV3pIVecxNHzwPtJyyZWkRILVDegyi4OL6NooOlPZFEmiGYyC4LHxEOdrPL64Eys3jpGZXIBnYfEue4LWZEyCxmgHpm6Lk4xEg9l1cf4igE3jmeq4uYtSsGwDGO2ZkeHP9/yikLYpQnBF8h1sLS8ue5RqTFNQkQ5TEmRxW1OZxvu03HeJgRNYNQRVmjVUfNnBydA1bpkLewkMc3XxENhDrKe7DCIQ4mVJig7vDOq7ZbS0nJnjYcDKoGgewMpF5lYwyv0Ac2v6UHPrvwInZwtUiriF9SAa2NK9Sm22k0@35PqnZQ8WHN3y5uzgIHbgSWvq9woGplvM5XJ4CM7clXg4QYGzxJaTjUNncUw8O7z@yn3TymLU@CV4C@/AQxoAFKFxagLlBKcmxtDeRE7lwvEcG3flfPA4JD@Bp81oGacVLG5/c0bCRyiReWaJvccMYv7eM/@OajAceZdBYPHXm0FsNEOvZH@ZHLAHPTp4ok6wJI2QUb9Z7FrAiY9q7UZ6JO6FpHE@vMNHvQm3IcrPzX7fSbO3jttvr8h8d2g8wsFBNEKOg@BSQl55PLpTIs3MK6sfuVcDQSLXv/OLmfDSXT76SXuZXHOIM2kKtmMnZnd/MlTkxjsZBBOynMJsppjcxO09XRmaKJmm0O9Hy48xA7IfBD3Qh4pBfJoFhjZQ7KUKXUDROt68yVcH43jKLmQZF3MoMRCVnwvDeXY/NDJ1MbnaB8eyFcg6Bku4XY62flPxUk6WgAfMlc8n@Q7yMMdxCJrw3MSHxbgt46FTv/0HR7dx5AA3N9IYb7AlNnLeWDQf/mA81ix2Nep0oHrxkfiaf9SYj45UZSZPqxSQNaJgXfPbMdgzSrLjiWPvcKnN6dQ2YoQ0Cs00E4fjlX@3PEp@DRTVD/iJyya@zkC1PhjT5SqhPqNhOFxAMa93MMIFRpCkL4zqt9dKvV5nq8NUitXrz8CRybD6szrbQ49nz9gevD/D98fVQrFY5ivn9tQb8Hzme96yZ4CDmiC8yG0PXiGM7mfCrhQW8Wq2upour15UK7Wyl23UnzWz2S64/u73f/p3//RPsnXx8j2@PKOXxrsASNO07Kpxs/r4tozvjb1mcrXVWB02k90yShmq@9eup/f1yDYxzfgHuUzX3zlvqAwsWrVaTbLkp0/cdT4KnW7oxJsPwuh6f9jTKTojDLVqsp58/BhclWryJ0kVT@4Q/nrg/xH8mYq6nOaLibU0fVw/3T08jF4uFFxa2kFLEyfcdbE4zbI9CzL1PuHPnmcaTNNYM8PeB@Thgu4LDhgnkSVxxSgn5jtBpJ87Wn1Pq1QpYb78lBYY8XVPfDXawOvS8iJ/gRKF/X/tXUuPGkkMPsOv6AFlgA4MQ5LNcxMpueWwu1J2b0w0MD3NBImBFt1sgiL@@9qf7arqpjMvZbPJKodEDHS9XC77s9t2IRiMG907fy6hc@jjPgk8fv6FJKV25bjx8mm6HOv2cjAePf7l/aDdbmNkROeeJhBzGC3z9xsnQbAsIt2kol5GR4bWzr3xlMcRdcjEaLfvJTSPw0TrOCxxoSQvGPUKO@1OUBojoimlchVhw93fGwFtaGYZa1jMjpT5BunWjA22Nw3cowm4a9OjzxGu9G3JTbXb4AbB4PZgrnhSvVreFej0l8vjbnnrMKlUYqh2KMQj6x4c9FLXaH8T3Nhnqole8RM9sjdLmnG/WmwvFnzjJpIm8o8knYjyPd2sxdKqIvII0vIsnfGLTznRsmE@aQ/AMOVc2GXCbxe4COmCK@8K4LO7lglB0nlghKN1OGac891dLCVVYDWjj6TwuSCi3CkNNryP4k7CUPxSDSVipL3JgTgj7JrJk0xV@tuH2YI9OMhbAzQa@wGXWU9b4oWeclo25oi@0Xu7AaCnJ6mFs@JCdghVXrIJyk4RIgo/eYSCtSQattFksZzU3TWNKEUMKcM8kEhkklhumLm@eMVwkvTb6slquLztclooebNVns81UEW3CVE4kiW8pl5POk0ZTLklvI07ztyJCtdnrJR@Ij5nP5jUHKHRaZHKBaUHOXiTIw8lLq5disfFlewscs/SYp5IqpSMfmCyOEM5EP5W6qZ8cSAyHiQc1DYYI5xEmoWqkaDYat8P6MRZyXz@PzjoPQXNLMRI5mtVW7KxYw63OyeeSL5HxwnooEwUnSOcU0rBRokxF@nFvCi16UvSteaXyip2Rno@5BNEPAbUrVCWY4PsOmwnEiZKbwvCZsFrv5GgfSrR1fW8Z4thrSaxWK6lLAmFM57u84eTRzadcNZ0gol8fHz75R2CcmVdN8@Fj2VPPKtGfheuHAGd6xRFXsTI5EcHKi2qNBmM@VLgCjVInFaOgZfCx6XuAwZm5g41OWRUhbyyXQIJ9oS38YvNdFdzyf2/OW5pK8/WXGqWDh89xXxAOtoHk5/RE8vEoxvXZe0J/JgaUGfxO0f@0nqzIOQvQeqqUcJ75P2gbh6VoWzpusMDIKXMCpaNO@FeVpraen3r9@XWg47UbvhsFRy6AdLJelrYQX9tiDInbWr9SmmG7rH9ubMaElqCwUWm2@4oyaFepzMmD8e6szT3m7OrYw2z4U3K25oVWXBoTNg5@kLtIX0ujPevIdIOLpzXm2L1tvj6mB6@O8xmPnNf4q56wgVTgsEKEaa9oX6ij2Pce/2VzAKWA3MSBJKpMs1T@txsCvJQC7P1W37xZvWpe9w/aZ20@qPHz3ot2MkOh7WTnCyjdpJyRPWarYRUbU/SxBoh93cqInx9Nj8/J8ShNy5QUx3N/XSq3Y7ZQ/7Zibt8AFXbghBPW4Eszwe0ifhCaY3P2Xp6cTnFx99Xf62n27ekhPDnH0vZzz@5v3ekjPjmVfzyTs7o63OCGq0d28meJ260RLjMp4R8kgLQoEilVIKDCzUESPcIIGO69eflxQZkCNcvvguHnqE3aVMnglByiQ2fSE3ACUwATk8gO@1UviPeVBMmRz07@YifxCCoAkj@wTJ5gm@lhUD9RfSK25RK@vmKamC8LkaTVv1oQQx6bCbX1UtZSebjxM0@n6hhUyQfTi83i2KuK9tblq2LG/UjIcWGryXRZXIVQa6GN3/JCVC/4keUVzaMzi7DKu2CdXC/4zmdUm/LQFB5KqgRZr0E9qORG@uH29GDBjVVpIL7g0fgj@Pdiyv2RtD9KzM1uMA6F3ELtgPrZZoH5oZUHHR6NnKrPigZHzwPIgpPI85YJoto3oV7zDvMJeAhTNzmfgub/Uc2cuUbJtmpp5LZpRpGLTLM2/rIH@5HxwO8LQitWuIUNM5XlxZtqeZEYLwGd0PTCeIM8v/aYL3Gciuhv4BUlp8ZYpeD0kErgUNLjAvI6UAMNHO4C1hrCEZCJAGRk2kFNKFzKyhaybq@RmyIUUJPypyrINsQk1tpjXijLvaUZ9/BiL2feobeHALCo8RT5yZUVbt5xaYvg9mr5zWYzbWMKUPIHnkF6jFrjRHu2OBaQqX7hBrdjVAyrzo6yS9fjUxlApSptGs269jXiQ5NGA3PuqsVsCeXQLgDB4QrfdQAXbzXDCZW7Y420JD9MwPDcfT6gsRiGQtL1MDUfydWjxiQeaU2lHPESUrNZp0@J0RM6KpJ/wjyspRCflzJA0KQddh0D6ESBFMD9HbeCK1NFg3bvaa@mR1KKFF39GTUwyA3GKlZujfj1vBexCC/ipntlblghQLIEUenWirkeu0HXfcFt3RpfbUuaZLI3ikt4jnOMk7Zvc5LPWzbDVsRdR/1ojs6qOEreSA6iP08w3azQVMQpMEBWzQYWt9XB2@e0jIyS5kRd64v/CH2oTm6vyf/t9E4R0l@xwEOIBwbOmB8xr3qBitCQCghDmjnXt4hUruE@dpRPFQDXARpS5xsGnykqrrWIeR2BVo6N58ioHbgVaz1mpqHKGrXNou6kt87XeDVUZqwI9x5qfJe4A9Wt8OwY9WieVpSEsV1WRJX4XIODyOdG1zWFYxRa@iXCCXzKBHjZCnCucq6JIT4SxBeVQodE4f6slr/gzygT/jTeVgPRFi8ehziPTRDT/fN0lG@njpoehV9eEEXq0opAdBE7q@zIo9@Ns3bErRKz2uYFA69H4dLb7UTN2VVVyi9nhdFFz8ZiS4Odc82H7K3gbWP1OOXij4oIeP1TxSHZZYaon/hpqD/hEH53q5p4cqFkbTPC4kc7fkgj7w4yguorxf@9SPbcaKTpufnpI43nI2/LagLTsTHTXUBnaVRDpPidgrTjHQZXkUhmZg8laplpq29XRbBMAvMX6s/BkrNtGBTg7pDeBFqtvCrq1UiFcA4CJCdA4grhV07ErOIDSJpOOY/tZBKYyb1yGd6kmUFUXyqw@oadD5YhGCsN@tpcSOI5V/JSXZ7tORqsHzXQIUP86Mm37l5W0h2E1wW3xiXtWP4tGMPz@J2Rtji4R37@LY4zTtoqZ@Wm3mLDyoc@DA5iMS0QYttP3Tmq9QKX7ndHfb9hC/fq2KIv3v4EjvyJ2UQE3sQk9SCGP@AtkrY8YZ27nmIBzq2S1jIscIeGW9VHo/OjY23qh0vT7nCcOSf08YrDMtf1wxbfFxpC8eoOiD8j7UDsayVMz1p6dmeRN39Ay377dXww59q@P@shv8B)

A couple answers back, when I was looking at CoffeeScript’s Literal Programming option, I noticed that Coffeescript 2.0 was out, and had a nifty list of [breaking changes](http://coffeescript.org/#breaking-changes). After playing with a few of these differences, I came up the below, new version of the CoffeeScript line which makes use of a difference in the application of destructured default values. Unlike the terser function call difference, I was able to express this difference on a single line, which was more valuable because it allowed me leave the number of lines alone, thus leaving the Klein answers correct.

`###; console.log 39;` became `###;{a=1}={a:null};if a then console.log 39 else console.log 180`

While I was playing with CoffeeScript I noticed that the line ran fine without the `;` at the end, so I dropped that. (A one byte golf feels like a drop in the bucket at this point, but I’ll take what I can get. It’s not easy golfing in 180 languages.)

Also note that I added a couple `s`’s in this line, so I needed a couple preceding `p`’s to balance Alphuck. I put these at the end of the line above CoffeeScript.

Comment: VIP score: .001707. This is more than the last one noted at 176; answer 177. 1L_a. caused a jump upwards that has been about half caught up with.

Answer (score 7):

## 182. [Bitwise](https://github.com/aaronryank/bitwise/wiki), 10027 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]      )[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_      7 )(22)S    / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x18&1&          -xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              /112\     ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@             /"78"oo@  h#115 o# dO 8=,_        x-----x ########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspsps      # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++.._+++++++._         #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[===============================================================]]        #
#<<<#QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqTqTqTTcTcTcRQRQRQ                        #
##############################################################################                                      p
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#  
#**  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9 >[4O6O@]<L+++<-][PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                          _         _               _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999\[\[yYyY
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"' pp
###;{a=1}={a:null};if a then console.log 39 else console.log 180
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|******[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss          <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s       e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !            <``=>  ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

#  *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=96los*81''cayY
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss_ baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                       @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155" )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//      $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/pppppppx     eeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkggQQJPgACVSg@uthdVeSQrKrpAVGsRCJBZBHIRGcCJFAstu2eZHP7OJPuZufO5nZ12zOrk2nNdB/WTpLZne2ayUz39Wx/RO/HNZnmH4zcPSJfeJCsmV07gQQyMsLDw8MjwsPD49Uy/O5vfpPCDztye5OLnjtkQ8sfsrZnX1mexp5N2FPD9kvFVUlCqLp3MepbztAvSymmM2Y7pt2GdzZ0Ly3H/mh54F9kbOC5F57RZ8OuMWSWbxoDy2fuaDgYDZnbmR9tlbG9vvvBzmHMvu1cANjQ8gaeNaTwNcZeOz2j32obUyGlqQQHHoT7bNfqfep/GjLT7fcNp@0D5DpjL13PtxDetHzfxegbjI33LHMK6SaAGp7tvqi/@nIqaIuxL4FEY9Czxsxo@UPPMIe26yBPCuzk1euTo6kYus7enO7vT/sW2dc512H7I/NyOmiVvfZ8o2dM419j9dHQPRhO@5dY/cJyDFbUtrTidOA6e@YZyShUnEee2x6ZyOph1wIKsHg6ds/yJRPAa2wgKoWGDpZinmW0ORhgPXH7VpxqnzmW1Wb@wDLtjm0SImaNh5bjQ4K@xmzI5bXd67G21YMIEXYzy3yXjfyYV6tndDVTkzquxzAV1r/sMZuZgwHjQaxnA0n7hU1mYaVhHyG81/XZeNBnvt2H4KHpdjqWxT5agy6T2q7E4GMOpjIVvi1bAONYAWOsARQ@MsbFugJcCvhz7RmDAeRWcGBo96Fq28O0zyzDt7HxQBTfctrE00HYrFxmOHF2sSsbChcyPvIIt295WDAa4WVdy7MApRFWbOXas4fAS@RFnR1ZhsdOPctSk00skSQk5mIKQ8yIRkW6vZ3eO9xPQ9HyGJoxgKL0Vk9/9JVkMK3Kls8r8K3KckXae7XLbpbP0M1bFBT/wFMMlVW/Y37@7MyC71hv5S@8WwmwSsCVHsu7g2HeyA2AwNwQCMwb6ERX7qqoDXqxhNn2VFnEKhyHakNpsAOHvclSzsyR56HUiJhqXEKme65zAfyEzHojB/nhsPUCFIHpQqPPMusKuAatjMrIvSYOn3ZtKDQfiyTWKLjsI4aC9INKLDgapOu7vRHBQUx/iDUZuAJREeNBh71hHcPuYRQIR1Scas/yR70hxhk5bSx5kG1WW2MBGabbRqC@ewXJGYCUPKDi92OtkogCYCgIl7KKQT/8iz9rX1wAnrppul5bVNc3rO2aJKUNIhZEH8MK6zpGj8gCuCymzqNDAldGz24bQ0zemYgkiAhK9dod9drMhQS9axvaaNe4gnYNTcscWrySc8GeZX3jkssSm9dcyHjfaEHBUgKUNmU7x57uQCmZlpSiOpPrj4adTZYb7LG0n3@nPCkrT5bOLCBO1dSV5Xz@ogIVTlshL3hL31Vz3tQTss8fGr5rt6XBZNh1nSLLmUw2q@7AcpR0Akc6m/ZaaVVDGaeoFbtqah3baSvpbaiLNUg4rVbMqtmwy83KVPR4koDmGtFgc7UUU5UlEDnUKK7yfcN2tMGEvckJVyzM9c@R5RisxbyRMdN@V9wjRR0b1ksXKwjIIc3vWdZAKWi6imIC4ebmGwPm5XQKh8hw2W5m0ql0Jp51wgA5TWQUG@up7aLY6g262KcBUxx/AP2Ah3XXNKD2@NgdDEG7yLIW1WvqQ0CykEy8ttKexVogSIN6RE2SNzmMn0NBKTBETSjZkq12rCGDEIC2PPRnpHHPvYYEiSbsZEB0OJiocQFFA5F5Ruo8Izwl8klm6dIBgYLYWhbbzLVsaATY3ECmizofyxuArxY5DGDjjSQme/rGBLCYvFONGgyzO9CW@iAevAkzLZQ5IHws3qFgIiNqfz7oU6hZFXLFUinZxmaa2NDL13M/ASH9MX9nS8LM1xMqA/Q8Heua9QznYmRcoErnQBTDNK3BUAgqyIk/BFE03d@QZ050nprflZafTqdNnUigWERpoJDnpSe6QgOli1Dqcj0QpswQailr2x6Ipd5kOnUAuJpKXH6PIAkC3ssLSAg0AKhk1tgyR0OQalCBr7u22YU6i9Q5XC7yTmg6efCKpw6SPdcJk0Zi9NrjoqTlQy8kYyGKHJboLB7oXBFVLeFBhR/3uBuz4ffnIHZDEqEjiPlqeUODuncPzr7ruHOQAiNDtAiSDOHlAJrYCaqT0HEFahc11lDHDIsIygykBrR8qH/d4XDgl6GfsIfdUUuDmpI/9SYHw0MHK0t@6E3socvdrZ7bArHsQ/vMBynkzVHLHk9liPzCMvzgS1eggHV8VoWe@9sR1Dol3fFBYJL/DgLHgmQS3ISC/8oASEAaMErp@CSK90GonEwcU5E1akoaNDo5y2RsuLIKDowV8mXH7aMUYm9JMUBND1R82@mAtBIyn0S@MberC2U/6XXptPbBtR3lJr20tJQup2sg2ZeWnoBrG11P0JUB1xNy5ciFcBq6KEaWXBjaoBjo10zfNgLMY7WJxTbGXumjPVCMRrm82swaDV08i/hUQdSBZAPoHD4AT1qtVtGpqnLtGjKqtTrJ3O@gdD4xPXsgmPCVcWXwd8GFVWKD3R@4HiqwFexk7@ZJv@pBLwhKq9lVvPRZo3DWPLs5a2fObtNZjK1WjGoLMgXpKX3twnNH0F2qjbVyTm@qamMVOslWNV1IryjKZq4HCRmq@sWmmjE4t5W0BVJbOTtLA1MFfxpm1yN842xRVUNWAR3YMYNOqKS1m01Iv6U21Uwa4qrpLAwxquk0cMZEJviUaayZCQYdHn/NGbOTyUhUDV3vEr8zYh/8NBhe8ej7UH93Tl4kBqX9S5CuzPR7qIrkPK6NwGt@hXu26RFqXGV2QBqrA90t5AB623Y4MnJcJ@eMSH8m5daNJ0SDQYQgP@x7UK7aCRhE3LHHMECAdj8JFCHsv1EX2oHhptuztLekmsgMGg7D5q7N1YaOeLeimX5UB0DvAeegZ5jQsJPozmR2Bgihnufz80PUygziaVWJRjX35RE6FtNwkH9tm7T2ke13kb2gWeFQwusAV1FlB93AIq4dMBP6/AvgtDW2h1yHh3p0glGeG76iotZY51oXKnuoMSBRgQWAunPXhPGOBZoDhvLBI9tzrmzPdZDJ2h6ghgpfwTKYQj6PvVCN6vWD4u5i/s5DDhyb8dZjvI1jnWau6Zss77g998JlKwCAVVPTeMU@cEwgAXS@IQwvmW9/JAbVL1wY@CTroIXdvY86or6@GmrfBkLmCV77ALKGzc90BLAgzycHP9mDHkIvFQpAf/BWoE@YyRiW6Tyip8kiAGGe62G9wZL8iTXoTrxEdfJdMYqE@uRavGHycb0BHSpQJVr4R4oab@TcB9p5ENQOXPPyvkcaEpoy4qOMRO5BGYR2KrLDmw3kMDXljb4BKxJIZwo8Kt99kJ2n3ZElWWbXZfIZaBjFGsu3ras8ChwZBF0XVOUcJGV5pIyF0YS5UBq6I9Dq2lbP7tvDAzJ29RxUXaJuOQjdgQYWITiyraEkxhuReEWDVCRrnQsOvzfGDsmXLHqyV4e7e@dH9dPnVTk/8r18z25BDW5b531QPHuWL7PpT4odW4BMxP942Tt23WGVF9dlj937SWGcIPqL3fMXB8@O68ffcCIIjW/3Rz0DSSkvTwFg9BMKDlpVzArY8dx@qJH7oiCWV5H1VsK@i8NTEbqGoSNh3Y35r6N/Hy22mildmCbLufw19BSAGwiIVlzqwy4yGYQkq27oKSA3CSVadjWvFXhuoWdo040NeuLo5oUvjiQw3@iFW0TuOyN/EMvZja6T/9Ww08FeO/QukvdlDqt6L/JeJW9uE04kFbBlJmgucIhvjfBxW/JcfDNBc4FDfCWOD23Q89FNhcwDDZGtEzK0Wc/FNRUwB5BXy1MQhC9c6L5e2D7NO8TrqRSqWWeSHOiKCaVIjkKKkc2G5a7mG5vkOCJqQVDJL10cokSu84KmlxBLiKJ/2ZuN2YGenn4SoDNEzYbwlttvdehnDkBZ2DFASKFZHrnyFdpi0dTigt5lXRMYjcgIGXDLdoz8MT1wbDaPnuQoM0FMy@qMQCXJg8qM7nvAclubBNlptexFoMAXJD14zgHzRq15bIMRYnfGEMESjB@OvGHPaovnf/m9NhTAbPF0jQmpYaHjHPhGdaOzsLREVHyhn/klSzAfRj3bIDaQ6z6UpoG2X6MXOuajxv6E5XJdw@ujtiMKFyon/oAIuqOecco9qzdqW8FzfiLE4qS5g8d27D7lCJ6ortPgZEH0KWMNj08Kb8812oSFq6W2FZU2LxdrzBW0mN4DUv4BdAY2FRZNYgy7o@GI/@K8xX3lag/wO58r5WQlK5SMlm7lXd9o2dYd9cAzLkdtNze4vKBMI2nri2o7b0RoAsh1esYld56jcz4DeBY9@@LC8oLnIrDrLmhapCLmr@lxR1UJ@jlGmotxF06vx38XgQSzxKFjMZ/sHv18ToWkKmJCq0HW4tRkLsYme4qxPaM1QVW5@/k1CxMkBQIET9XMZAqr2IWFluhoEnQwWBwf@z2Kv7U1PzafFOUsmadA5vlkaI6bCSjPYnr0nlYPPZfdN3q5YjvmXCjEAxNU5JoDSuOmnNkzfKhMQ1Ec1hUUH/3cVcGxMzKxWkWuO6p3RE4wIbHIth3FGdim27P9AW9x4mWRNJ22CkZocHaafqKo@DbL3zYMj7Cjz4Wu@QLBNYdoX15Q3x4g4LhpF43nsQqkuYt4Z7rX@F2oYnTdK4v/zu/0Ps6l6gGiKtejmmGbc6K3zfuqK85Q0s98Ll7OpWpo9ub6l9lL1/W6luOzolYIjFk4PWT0etzWfHpwuLhO@3bP9WGghL938QIGRL7Pf@fX5jjbbMPJkcUv7p4fTRA1YJqwcCwoTKN34fbWNy/yBvwsLPGR18EeQDwfKvlCyaXr90uuQEFyHV08F4r8y7x3eV9lILOgh9MHMecd/e088SXMzoszCMMInBOcn7n9wibF1PJ81LqoADyze21Mgudv0ass4m7QqwwmpF6D/ocRtjbBMfS4yv3bpLZ2d2rth8mkGbQb92UiVriXPQskNP3OFCkrFvTPjKEXCg@XUJ3eyBpZcyXGYeuDhau57pAVDyeqILKxLOw7eWAeWndCqI9i8PggqrH/xrc7BYzRs6GR36vlzJV3A9DJBzjePgLHETpmI144o0GicGO8Ox45x3dzrjsIWrbbThCJIZ8rkTbv16USartv0XeRir/Xd2GI7PZBZ3AeUP4CKZnE@G8CMflEmD/YaGv07sRbZuE8I@i1oH9AqdqXfg4Nlg8TPMVFY3sC3tqC0ZtjDSf4u4jb8wRpy3V7n1M6IE/bNqploGziir/7SmlG1xFTziyyYvhoEWl1FtkveF8jBprAPRxULyzoI8jSkDqHh5TyjM3zjl4rZgG9b7wJPTYZiXzPDNyL6D3Gxq1rm9rGnQRzddRtWT2DP8bra3fh29JWH6ISDQI9lyzmaGXndvVoYiI1JYIGE2CW3YaxStfqW/R6h5JvtD@M/OCxEGjs4ndOsJYnK/GCeAMb2ryDvwkbfkwrGroOjK6Ghndh4fCkh5NLwneRnA2Mz3OZe9A3Lqz9eytXZKXA9Uh8UBc559srynyJgAnR7pEkfOTnOpfWxA@e8/XjiQnlOerfiW1eOzfRGHpvw9byc23u96h9TtftOl2r61HjCN8WNQ@okUO@lPuuTAD9XcO/xAVYJJOiYV3Xj3O35/Z6D@EuykQuIV13vp12D5dOtyHqZ@GdGC0IEI97TXrQdROTqA9f1Ha61gh6KN8dugMrR2@LQHto/OG/803PB4dpn721La/NZ4/REmgM7VbPYtc2kPDBj09ZzjcstXqugWv87lDigTPB8yGmKtP17rWDXBjucDCgx/mgN/Lph0y@uc58W2aZ7ROlD6kM9pBP3PMqa124LbNr30dSyzKGjn2ZD2w6/HV@NU8KY8q5zXK76K31bOCVN9GwElTj4Sf4OJjf8O0XYifGnQrJzsjzJvcLh@SUbGh@5ZMG6FhkgBGzZ3OCqevH1SnBKow7Zi7EZNvCGkXKNCrOOasA2om@0ByUWIgjWNBbXR3ewyXTNS/v1ScWGjLFPC2Z9OzYXDP4T1sx7ibjuZBvMDpUno8ufPX@itttg16FP3MrSf2CVxCcWPJ77nXM8AxN33DEY27c4ov7U6fZkdKdEyVlpr84rx8e3I/M7NkDn/@yXKc4V1WYnWOdhZrMH/uKompbHf57n37Xdz1cjwyKRM70LN9EOzjKYC4bueBx3AuQxbkei4AD2Lnkz07pztNQkv1c7sevrAsD1ye9sHGpUs@f7foA8/Ts7kMQ/2hk@PaPRu7Qmotzepb3IShfGhe2@TxRAgHCgLtiMQt/JIQles0WxHXX9mlZaOBYpEdARbtbHE4b3MMtSncbR2I6klijx3IHLFjLFzrQ5I/hxty04uq7O5g8qEsiW6p4zmLiU@zHtOMmXJvtZ8WSIvCzPbExxNeC3VcpWn5FK7WDlbsshevHRyjChq6nMYJTFCOTUVWJR0Jr8IUDYAEU7X/BtfF8a43PerY/JFi7wxoNtnwzLhfK@i2rMrkss2aTY8UPrdTeGw9o88oxj95YNprV5XQul15OnzllVkiH4FYPsj4X3EjAdmx6cHojFjDH4Ivs0B3kuMLX/vtd2lcD3X4b1IfXMOqkLsT1@Ap2vj3iFKeh//NftsV2Ixhj@KxvgxAChuBeO7dvdd3rJzxdkXp9MDBwuxLigDrb44vnczt15l@jnsF3GbnX7PX@6abYuyA29sHLEXaIMSp44eKAF1ceDnnhcWrCVWQi4TBWkCnT7Y36Dmh27WHX19iJTYsKR160OghcCOYMPVRv21l2wNoWTvbRWlEa0fVc95IWfSMl//kv@Y4NWjEqVvIFydNOrViKuDBUp20SpumOgOoAyUfLcwWIgkwG@TJCewm0AYv7q7iOkraSQI3MBRspKBm@m2KnfsJyeyyNexZxfXbF7ijL9eMv3zQKzep3rJ@3/svv5dUbwTj5i9zWui9nWQBSucWKFQ8uQXAUmmby8ljmCYbLaW2hRlzz8gAWGbyS4YraoI657kC0GtoMR3u/wtooNuAq6KZyDnZU9GkfHVVY65p2VNAyNgflLm5Qc3xoYPCqEmre6qrLyogP6XMnQ1aCBHFXigEuvvOOFpji7gCMsjxmn1gXK1nOxEWP8MYZ2cMNKf3qs2D1x2p8jU5@12qNaGL6qqgVV6uUneXz6naNXJ7VdnFjWOPd2bhYyJ2NN/aaeT9g6tnZ@ItC8cfAdRdGG8uP89jy9l7t3ixrtcKnT74xYbJ8m67wRUcgJpZvjg6O9k5O66evT6AUbgPxs@96fSOSNViLaBlj1@3Rljvgi2db/mfIn/ANwBWFLRtsGzcOq6oUX6FHoILXck5e5s6YaErEvif6vPi@FQufBRAyrWOzoEZFK7uh28DChFqH7EMujAa4g5AJJGIXFFU3G4U9tqSQQ7jGa45QJZ7JrApcywHXHsgztjjXT7jfQ1h3L5a7@fdkLgiyLkyvEYbzLM5lwe0/SL4H0GP@7vnmWO7ON8HckW8ADX2DOPv1gxevj/eS0aCy0ZPEb3WrJNaocimNTY6bBYJtX7ScX0REu0hVZjJF4K@iVxvhhqCWNby2IFtCSpp9HplqKNEvS1HFBM5UcY99s8J5oShEASojFczW1BLajj2OkRh01jF0NzyLoTTYl0PUAeGaLDCnaAe8hp8gG4hVsCtog0ckzYXgTvtxPSgbtDjMGnbWI5@3uQV9Vtj9@Az@Y91T4Co22ZiJfk1vshwrwrdnwUCjG8KqFd5ZsWXOCHmZ0y6H9OL@a6Cp/cGggQktIBKrhKG77hkD3OwpoF/BYKDMvh25tCUhECahonGNCq/BDxqgojUNzA1tdXCGuHEz6MAI38H@SRXVNK6jkaCP17mRgz0WAMU2/u@NYbwBla1DQp9vIeYsd8Vu1aDPJHuVL3anheqCz65sn@xZWAgdVHZ6ICkxNyLjUBh8Mwqr93xQTtrQj4OqMsQ@F7QUjVbB8qWwOYfJKaiTWqg7ZpksIaxfnd29CH3qtQn963seeZngCLMvzdlmfWblf/gXf8a3Vp8Nwf2Hwj0uPIO3PxZvHXD/8yBE1@HtX4ZvRXj7GX97l0eOzu4n5bkJmYgMfHNwxHwyuSGL@sY4lntsuFiUtjOCYu0Dr6@IdQjOsxVxJsKjNN4A56G4gO2oPqDGQOlZXlPB3YDlfB61a5wn0Wi9pjXm9jbaHPjtCDfFg5KTXy@tr@l5IDJ3FSCkHToXuECQI1TVMoga6coeVN@3TLa9vc1k3zR6VnW9wlmeXzbercrvQ0KXAVbiiniDQRyIEsWAsJqIpiwbGV3FqNg/pPU0ioq2y0sQtC2FHACiorcTbHEAdc4VrILq4VjjIWkkk2CAAXLQoUXzFj8aIUCUA0QcN27dnq7l0ZI/XCEdq/davBjktwh2gmBleV4la7xjZ8Mzpym28DOoML@cU@UccP/RnH39Ye2pz24oV6a3g2Nu2NMTx8WloftALVOK@eJqXl9XY21KFqiAXmxBnwAltBlog6Zlf3AHfn1n7@Crw6OTmY3RBJmeBkuzdG07c5bTso1m6EhP1fqAqc/28ycvn@0HrIxTFc2YIkQ0bTpN5rzUpildkPpbvtZyNm0KmElILzwUMc1P5PZpZcEs9ig0HwPc4Wu8ZlJV1JvbRnO7duakZpL/NO@wiJS2gpULXGc@HRWRZnNkzkGwgvQUDxzytWCrQVGOjkIJtxfw98h78dbm8PiiaH9zsFZVop1H4cYjSVuwihXyruV5UrS5lxMW0AuyJiBVR1KjBE1pZtY7Tg0TeZk9aUnsswiZdMhtNHRmg@HAsNyzTQ7tk4Dmlhw6aADG8Aex3tjs0koXGnlOaCQPoiK0NbdtMtsZXrDlJQw5sfp27jSgBwVHtF9ZbNTtQt56dqtiVBtjFm7UuGvbruYPevZQwT3EYw0tJJAbRcUM6Nu4CXesbm81xX5nFmxLztDO5qMR8OvIHbDIOrVrBa5jUFHY7giQmzi@@WrUB7gOPY4t7CUsUFpyEBn4mA6IaOBeXpEHrd8uQepa1xq37QvoaRQ1CyLpC12P9kQbuKnXSYMc5qz6EpcCxhnzWfu4YxwzGoZmO21rrOCWuXITuQP@6eu3V2lVnqkDtJlcbB1uT@8qD4SFMRStNtqRPSUQtrZCQZBsO1tbWteXcCMNKMOQ4snQewFO6EOVTt8YMGVE2/J9pjF6Vc4UJ@sPPZXlatifXTOHZTI0qIYHBYCujKAdctm0/1HBU2yUfBXKGX19p42Pj/aANXRNa4KbElHZMhrUdkDdQFOUKsHYCKKUCS10wPBXRopA6WwjRfy5TMlKtDMWoOYGU0O@6FIDBF5QrlntcbQNMdYCOVe3tsqiNJLicItBtdieIzEA7RwxF@imwF@xFQK4hkIMoHY8q22DQHn6teU40F4VqDN9aJ3MGEEl89RscNJbNjqdh1JIcRKfi70VQGjy1J699E3PBX1mOV8h20zlFvr992fY8XdE1z/J/7d5LV@5UZZ71UkelDG1pix3q3pmdSWTWXZWlGUH1ZHHj9Gkc7sM2s65BgOjMQDllntqBeozaEfVZaeybGwry@1qcYViwCsMzW4gwnd@XrtZNm7zy49Bm8iCj8dbp7Ls04b6gqbpt0AftpDlfBbqzA3uDKfz2zD5ZTuTQRq05XMk4Lv82UmG@pWzkzxZjypCyc1f9AMxktRVwpKYOXeOM1B4l0OJXkKJLtbFnAfA0Zk9q/PC7tSuv8ZVhIwmPC3fj9evZMjDBYsQaCichJBR@IkGwMCxAkzE16yhqiBMfvOblL7OmPxkfVVxM09KhUomXdJheAjjutRTUFTzK7In35zt5q6YlUs3OkZJ@7Z5dHl09GP1TGFbLJ3aOZT1Nfkd2yqyh302WHHBh/0un1RqJS@l8iv64418/v3796CSw6dR02ogPuijNnLpZkPZAGdtY2Mlu765kn2aPg@oUpViUT2hIRE7s2174Lfb8HW7dNiikuKfJ08oLRh2wj/jfiJ94QheEET4pj4Xziil2NmGYaxk1opPnQpQt4WfVaaDE3834auzUont4edv/4@//cXf/pz@fkHfvzbYJfsIn8sOw39yf2zH3Aa6W52PeOAA6N5VkguDdLq0mj55l5ZSNTP1MaXrempCf@fo1sf65mP9ccTz3HjqkyySvK4Xz6J8xtiAWQ69Gfdhcb@QHyG3meBS6nPh8JjK9aWnDOqDBV0Qfsrlp0lC5Y1N2XXBswv5LDE3xdqHbLOaPQ8gxjn8jIMsCApYlKsoJHpjca8UC6KxCOZz4aRUcH5YrmF0mmxYxz922sK/4yH@vbl8c5l7c3ls4t@zS/x72cK/oxP8G/j4FxjDUqkoQ6JOh29hLZ/2C7gevrCgMbDPgZNS31WrvDyYKJd5n9kgTTsPXOcxwx57Ap8l@KN/@ISv@LtEPsKbQGY/S7@D@JFSjVSj@rt9ms0wN1Jqe3s79aMu/Xn499zBv9a3@PfiI/59e4p/pyb@Hf8I/xbKRin1D/p5GEsGEkvlmpnc7W1DezfOVCriH9SNSviGH@6CYm3e5nLb72qZTIOKt1ET5byda9Z4odOvdv5uG/Bmthvb29p5rTau5Zrvag0shBv8Mf1bfOB3ZQV/i7KcXzkjZ3W8fcyR7wbYUbIy/Ks11g7XD582t1/wNBtHL@o7e6fZ4naOpYr79Z1s8eT1s5SOr6XonYJX8f14r757@BoiHL3Yq5/sfXnwZu/1Efj7zfPa06cZDUTIU8hBrdmQUuMvMrVMdTgcnv/kfEVDjXOLK55EzMLP@RyXeJdSu7Xx63xuG6h/cb6FuT2mNHPApOYnxpGfNc4ak28m30ip99vvlcyTzJNCr3BV0C/1y5fuYfR/eDiGAHtc@OB6hW6hq7ehA2AF63VhUpiMC333UG@D04K/Qh@cdqEzLlwUnIKj65NxAtXi//6hO3x56AI2F2IOx4UhIi504HlxePgS8HUg7Q/wZxcKhTEQOS5cwX@hp9Pn3XkBO3Y8gQXeCoWzM6nB5PcW9P@antYKaW09nbabpfXBt2c3t8X1bxs0ZiptNRt42k5TZtn0@Vkj3ayk8v7ZWZ7rS3JxTa7QcTy3t@fnu/XT@vl5HpvQeHs58zSTewqfai2zLR5PUu1a5clZOYeVM6imqfz2k7Paag7d6xkogyL4beczn/mJUMKztnQmpZXrt2/f4vft9dU1d5GD@529DUPx520evLgLveCDoPl58ZOO8WzNU5RGqXlzC3rjWbqSFpqlwuhkLFk/Gxc7rCjj6F3ZUkF511dxiLheYmqttl4Cj/VNNacUcHTPo5zJg8HgTNbInqnRtpRqte55xgRtGMoaIFG2StXqmWx452dyo9jEuKXc1jpzvdzWqiqr6jt9exvSwCSKKnjL6bHseml2cxv/U25utxX6qPinquipQr2hZ01VAEAtwdv4RmHbyraCfuCF8W5ua@gkuBtwNRS1qd7ecj/lpnKrqNscbU0FzjHQ3P@R/kEj@f/P/8vXzAfl/zaFQ1KHrZVUpTWx1LV1ZTOzJf6qS8BZRV5Nr@JYI22kG42nK6srG2uNJ80VtoJftqJsn9Wa4wUfNZ2CFh00waqewvJFuaZVjmW9KMNwboDtsnJjVPXb6o1RxpH6bYXO36QZO1Oc9tVzL9jqFp/djPvpmwXsKCAVGT7oktIMKkFtO6z2YQMYqzWsM4xqAVObTL29gaZAYTDQVcTc3NnZuFBQWaVVXb5JGbcVzILMbmUBGTQmQq2kK7Q2Rr6Rlw2voTflW3n5pnWL1oAVXaWBYGmtUllZ4@5lRdG31otbxeLG@vqmvrEJGvZ6oZBnur5ZXNtcLW2tra1vltZBFKpqhRJc0VcEngLgEc7NSsXyDbOCMq6SAjoUJa0yKKbUmVRtWReQPHB5EG/@mVKptJQvwmP8xfpeccyWPq3Qp7EC5blZ3MysZJpPGytbW1i8TQr6tCRVcL6OL2eRczKXGmxzi1JO@X6Ef7smNfrjTpPObKnmGvp6qZlDRfHDuLMCpOgbq6mVAN5aPiKRuLK7Ar86/O8t@dTjD2i1zUaBtXGe0mNup7MEnl3DZy2cUvatXi84c@7a9Xrta7ttLUm@BZ/@kWGNLOt6NLq2ws@O7RsfPhgD@ow7P/zypz/88r//4Vc/@@FXP/3hV7/49fe/@Cl8/xK@P@PPn/37rRL@/vr7f/m//PDnvwLPv4bvf4Lvf/z19//m9/iX3v8Gvv9XzO9vxDcGx78S4PrjX3//87/49ff//E/h@2/F90@nvz/86//A//9v8YfOX/3wr/8Gf8TLT38GXPr7v/ol/v/8r/7@P/0S///X//nv/@pf/f0f/zty/Bl3/D//9t/z37/7/Z/@3T/9k7/7/e8X/P70zt/vH@D//T@Cz8PpfAieh@Trc32@/63o@V24EaUCdQBq2h/98G/@AOrqv@Zv/wze4D8M@sPwJRHCX/4wegEM/9OcSH/06@//5C/Ctz9IAibCAMkfQtifJ8L@8Idf/t4Pf/Hf/fDLP/vhl3@M0ii3tpWtZ3P6PWYgACw9AA4B1x8CB4AcZIktSUV64o/wZEvkGq9IpVUcxeb4J8M9Py2jXsrOPkkleM98yuNpgSz/SYSe4WZhHUJX1yi0APp1AUNL@BqExkhB29OTpwn9nxOy8ukpA2CIHAMmwCecUOGf@ZQQ6RiTwpdCwuEbJbYUxk8Mjbffv6/WEOApBENHSX3lNv7iC/g8qzJGI1p41DZZVcqyzSqeDoaAVXincHTSO@DCqzuq0i57hrYA9N4FDmGfOx6zsfQejTcZAq9xUFaTIPw78HjG0RA2RPWdBF4Z7rMLz@8E/FgifPgvlFt04zcIgJ8M437wmkEkmYBNLCNxCCaMXOMZDZnsGAiH8cb4zyJEAk9GAkZksvHBW5hEJvKSwtfMTCohPVNhmSiMUZqZJKoMm0F4V2DCW5qOyOZiERQsDJ3KZhA6J8UgNDUbJQyKMyiTSTIMYyYzlZEyuNh6RSS6kllBGzxb@dyPoIkSmMuOOz5xfq9EOY/jjaiPsBK9PEKGYKO0CaPC9SuayWP6@lqIWJUUOlOWqWQVsQag0Ekv/Ytn7lgpZGU5q6/PtzSoaEMB2G/ccrn6nb62IcGT3kd4vK04aBXqNl55om3DB@iQajc5dG6jE9S1dalWE7OUTJdqJ3unEOH0kOnFgsYahebN2kZxrbRWKq6ur5c2ivra@tbaemlztaAX1gulYlEHXXZrc2vjVqr9mI01dnT0oxy4x7lcvkhJVPXSRmVShYjkJdVIc@Qa5uQm54N2iWSdkT57g4uJ0Cx0k8OG@Qg@THoksUfgBR/AjHMqTMxlHxxWxIwnrsgOlXY@/SnrpS2ZuHRmOW2OWBrEPxKWxeO1LfZY587SeuQsoFM6xRPyX0FawEKHvcDVjUOXnbp8Fd0zy1wAsdPld9zseK7v/w4wzwznkgft2ngymzkMg54beO6K37eH3QUQrwd93IVief9oGPb6LSAQLd0c4Bn8eD3XnQewwV4fLcjly3CTFc6l0i4rAD8@@PL5aex5ulffeS6ts2eHr3anHiUBVGIv9vZPw9cNHhpELYUovtl78WL6VTxwILTEShvZrKZp8IPPLH3oqS2/C0B0bbEyIq8Xihuynj2fWDDEucnlbi/slqWvw3B4TU7BIAzPRz7hJ0APnTYbd6hVbK33XH9lU0@nTWPyjfQSl5Zt6XwLgu3jsnzAdu3QdooW3k8xGiz2hAd6odOzL7ogdq7dEACa3TlrGQZ@P/cDSKz4Z3i3x5CnQX4zIb1ZcOk5DA37eFIwbmQeSteh2extYCMLbWW8Hb9FGwJxKJim94eGh1epnaLoo0tMGO4ebeG537QpC9UJ2j9Jp3RbIAi3JAmnJu0OK0gaCqdicWuztLm1WtzMbm5trpVgqFvK6sUsjOc3tgpZvaBv6jCK39Kzm2tbq2sgBiG0tLUhpUDe2J18HnoAXZbpaTsmnuy4jUdkulq3JqXaVgdrPxsrbZWl2qHHaJPJq5tnBQYRZQlXv66Mq3JxDZemr@pMlyXZYCZL7e/vFPb3ZfkZvqBldacgy218KW0WChvPZNmikB0Q1UWI1MW3vXU0wcqyjS879f19xPABX4qbiEOWL3kIf@kFLxsA5uDL6ioiYLL8bYiuAMhdTtEmxRryl0Lh2Y4sjzh5m/AHcHX@tkbE7uELBmCkfR6yA2Gy/GUQCdRwWT7mcCKp50F@63VZPuAv9Tqi@IoyX@KZ@hpf6vSBSB68QTuQ5QtwXHiW5chyC5zYGmTZBJc5McCvDy48JcIZGrI84fnAnMjymKAN81KWzwN/SAfoef7c6A7b1gX/TDz@NCHoAILs8Whvv/Xll62Li5Y3qe99eUxBX3313PgwGXmti5aI2DqHj4uxIOiyP5n@WBh0fm705gd9DUHOVND55NwiCs@Nb4Ey8bnAhPrnX2HQVxA0z6InEMKnD8At/Dzrw/OZ0eJBwYeC6DluteQKVllsOh2FKq6RpUeLlJUbhuuSfMV4QkKwjBLQ7YCGM9pUc6Uno015fUMur8BTfiKvghOaBiukC4zJ6TNZVhtbzSfyRkkup588yaUf60@YvLEll@WNDejl1cotClBFveko4@y4WgCPfH4bGzQ2QXiC4iG0hlNrPNSeW7ggxszl3iY@29tvAQ63buKGulejPoxSrkmG4Kr6YAX0efUZCIxCxcH9uxa@Lo9TY6nWNoYGjKqe3YzKZQF7W7moNhDBJ/zZzslva2/lJounW9ooAFWvHbO4sb3duP7UBO2pqlcmKaOqFzcrY3xurMX1puWe4Q@X9Y1iuTFabuT05tJS4dPFtvyTGqG@hcwmzacbmxXwC1jBZVwopSAGboyAby4nYfigKspGZgpeu4CThLQsR0mnN4rptJquQNwlGbgumE7ziFi4QdnIIB2hbLaKEN2zhiPo7AuV25mUvcsySWrctIYplJm8DkobeOOekvmfp9mcni2vtErbtX8y8/lv/sm8z3xf/EhcD13XpdSt1MbzKNe2pNSNdHtzu10LUvyaTSZGJhhws8eMXWSWpeU0Zj69mhxh1qv1i@N6YEOu70ip3Kq75qaWl5el1PZpTV6VD7XzcIaplqc5zDOc5MQ5QO3sfHsp81tNP@W02lM@H10DjZ7lJc/CHXRtvGWQzwJtlrAwLpifyvyWH0hEqgJOqYJmeDmFssLsuSNcmLF9xjO0/V2KZonY0U1n5NBK1fJL1NIVo8w1nkYTGux3r@zezeZqrkYLrBSoZbe3VDPMQ1o6IaUcVziBkaCTD6HZKqDUl2Qa@FhscLL1buPd5ruXrw9fH@6zp4XyZnmT8/2MV5SsntbTUI5PoV@2j/ek1OCTW9K/c76qpMqD9OpaejVRdmdVscFYwfqvNHBnTmO12WxAfUOS4b1aLT7RS5uZtbK@wdRUDfc6FjeQ4@gCmZBbTTVTHMnahgpusuQX9VQtL7z1DV1N@Tn@BlFKKV9Kbb58jzaf4EI8u0iufJ4Ttny7fQv/tdsGDNtuafR2S//85/aWh8M/gYdv/BF9YoBxmCj8t6t52nmq@V1um/9v48/OIc@rvF6S1dT7ag3qw7vzd@cpKbXF5GIJx2WZvBiG8QaEqt@KQ3@Wv4J/7yKPFVBXV8I3eN1eYaWaDrFW8vn8mfqjIihrW1vrm@sp6TfAtTuWp0NouF6zY8HwB2T8nAWbdc9@aeBiVidctAmOl6OPeIPJ0@Dqw0CvY6jY4Ypk1OzifkLZi3nRjaFJv4mfxz1l6CtJ6LLpxlzWoWqIgnxI26DYCp6HgxvfVelGegS4RuaQtqPBT0WSHuEeRHxVArgse@wPVTTiFVTp0SMhif2h5g/PETlGEp45vSLdSsgeo932Gd0hhHO@fLe8gRuq3AE/Oa43YTyST9e8cCWVNrpjujGCV1iHUwG5WWGUIlGOmePJP@JgrVEHSdk/eLEHcWA836GlkyK27LXwgi7K3lJHZWGHAjzAa2aqglMEjoCADjy5DqL2cUu@SU2aZZiO4R1agglQWaZniZIs64iIDXxtQnRE3wHh5gNinrrCc8BWzkWyIg@CHsoEsBBzR/0iXQDjXZhZUXp4@nqjqbKbYBujgqFsmxXV2FZOwgWFwS/VpYhmvy1uC6pGbCZsejMLRVvh@zWVEE74RIy6lVaG2X6FF9WgIn2tmKAquZ5S@a7/@LH5btDoNytqvzrEZybTh776UrE5yMqw2q9C9Rg07GZl2Mhk7Ga1r36t4Dve6YUdu1D4fFXkDXLuVIEWXNLqq9mPDSf3ndPM7jecDJA8yq78pPoxa1QLqKpl7aqe7WW/BZ2H5wPSHFY/ZpyKsQ1fXIac2EoL6knGqCS8MMql0qt@bBhN1P16EDGT2YfMAJ1@o5fJNFVIvAeBsxErvcePjUyvNq70cjkVod6tPtlvDMHRzFTxvawY2@MnHxsjiF9W4FmFZHoqEA/xBK9vQ9qBvgrwmJdpRDqnkVTTMZDXr1ZXfvJk5Scr1aWlj41xrt/McvaXC1FtQOLHSHwltllZWfmJyqZYQnPaivyFXf5CW8Edp3YmA0zODmIxOYUrP4GQQSYTUH2L8vI0PnbGGiZ2N/K9pHSvA@1YobEyjZr5hUIoLuq@adsCnJ85MbDxBAU8EylLN3EZBIFh4u5hDDwbP3kiBUmLDXWQMgoXGKUbaLqgGyhxfzKdxsH48U/3ydd5YjiQueEgm26FguH86nqsuZJoogbne2YDQVAM3BRuK1xi8W2UIGxIegAMSQ@Ey6EUQSYJOSEgqyIQSisoIIiFcqLDjy6j05tQPqGSHbZ8ECGcDGjMc8iwsx@qJJugPtngYvY2pQcOaCrSI8gE0oB5sJusBoKMPX7MxOt2lenFDewLEAzhPmR0BJqhFBJ/AKWAA6n8AHUU5SElArQ9whBcxZFIaO13S0icP6FAhMyHLD@GQqNjKJSR4/NjW5BvKicDy@LRow@Z6pogCP5pjALxIez2NynR3ZfZzuHLo9ene8cv6yfwC6PTzfhle8E9uDO3YA7wdsuW7dBWV9M41q1vvjIZU3B0hpc04DXXbfbV6xesWHy1m8Wjk4H1KW6Xhw61HGKyfLrCxtdc7yJ/bV/a@b3E2aZ4IzHtqvXLdAGtWF5s0UkQdLN1eJhMdJaMj3ZD6MzFea@JG8v6lu@Lyz1zwUXpdNgeHavTx9NhoBWKy0Bpw1LifABcvZGlfWOefWHT7dddjiARn271GvLo1D4kvMSTRslQo6WtzUKhzApZdOiBoxg4VgPHWuAoBY71wLERODYDx5Zw6AFmnWOGkfTq6nrk3Iicm5FzK3SuFSJnhGGtGDlXI@da5CxFzii1tTC19U3Cy1IBN6npWh6G6WubQRgZIIbkWQI0@rTnGhBanIGE6GsznpDeZtJzY6sgEjrIHyJQsbgevYP0CWCrCqcqy@nI8pT5m/CEvkrioz2qsHueB1Jpb4y3FkOlU8sMj4GQJDyVzexZBigD1hC0lOo@1H9LLVMfNPQm5egMDMRQ1cN3iI53vkEcnS7e5tVnTnBxXjDHVpyLjR/SxULGxE4DEURyKsuJnpZjXEv4xbEuoYBFji6AKHIILIPk4SFBmqfeaG6Sq3cnmUA4N8kZojje0rxYyBuFkFeDqNT/E7ZqkB7XUywqbVADMCYUOtWBqQLFU8SqN3pZ/vX3f/q/sV9///NfsR/@/Ff/73/8H9H9H/Dnf8dTMoohwM9@zmgZCvz8K0aLTmgBTBSJ4FfL8g9/@kt4/R/@Hfvhpz/nQX/yF3J2LUQEIegVxfzFP8OfP8Cf/1POlkLAX/wRB8QocvZWSqhWCkD97K8Zg9QQS4jsT/@SMTkDCoYial6Dt/Fm7MQgjiBkQ4Nczelw/ouX1QKPC2pGBrziTY/eMlgAagy5Z@AJclHbA3WGGzlRSpuG2cXDN4SX66P@Y6IK4/raBdS36zYoPcIskYbc/z4rs3QGYdDCgoemVbkMF/kX@ZajUITNyHmgDu9rFKjoKt@QEhjeSlC/aSQw8TUcttCIVOd1RPD3lQXdRNCByEHNoqtJJZFWEBvNMuKWd7qrNhjqYqXFbogfOkZXtEridAg9lmBC3EwVG6Qy7QNDxujYoHhU8rD6Azz2phrxGxmLL8SF7DS6qOREs9k73J9qMPhpgYp5GZdIYUJVJsv3wCKnBbyKGtdqEp7TKwAahfJqM3EA0Txg@cc//rEsxfwKWIe8tkIYYpniIiMM0pNBxVhQMRZkdwROkjWlYnGKBuo4UC4mj@Hi0WIiKhktqlzYcoJyQDJgLMjtotlOb@R3q7OoSSInhd0s8hhKvVkV7eTMIZlTY7I6EwFwJuNUp8tyPurCDMxsQc2PidxO@CRKazGmRJxYoyDuSdNcCktO35pXcskE70CtNzMPTKhY@B0Tyj0wofXS/QlNFyvGTaBfzN/7xU4gJkIJHyHjDT@V6KCwa/xTqHqROEKKPXIqKgx56mLI07p2mRIMPy7sYXfUomEM@OeDuxLyrZ7byvdxlOPh/SjhDQo4iMHzpLh54OnAhSGHi1pwMFQyHPZagCeGHfyW5AvH9Sw/frKTuDjZSeOBW6Z74UCvlsU7G@xLS1yfbYlzVJP9StizCS0UT8WGoQ@i5oxCzfP83Hbs4fk5KJ@9jhoxEF81Ew8kSEsmRARXLL4SqraHA8XFu2eG6v04Sd/l0U5t81I5HIjANCRSZzCgM60eDL5YF@8aDy6Oxizy28dBI20NFTofuuv23QvLcfGsMYw9hf4gwo0EGYMB0ZJlRpaZMYrEIFoxs4Yqon792VHZ10XFUMP4xSSCBDOyzJvmMXLWm5Pc@cLkeLQgvZPPp/ckTu/J3fR2bM8fTtNMnmjtwefnJb2qRBgAMCJj9X4ysuKMzxlyEqSE3j7qRRThwSS2aYFVGymtA2hdgGsdqB/Z8M2nowcE4W8W8f/uAgyi7z20@EiZPZmAvOnTtfQ0RPOD6XgFwA9UNVpWGUsurNq7D0xLDHRohJdlMgkuB8@1gIY5GFhOdC94gPieOo8rrGbqPS27qvLAOTR5V1l2WVxcRLvnbatnTKy2IiCzMbxBjo8to03y6mEZR0FHQg/GAGTILGT1hCpG5w8RUHlBlTGyV6q6uFpxEDusPTQZRxQeLOYfGe6mRTMaQat8DsT1QIKm6PBcOut4MBlM@JllPTpMMJCjvP/hJfnKFacV3skQ4AO/717PRsmqd4nPYyXM0gN6hBBWS2aZTv4Iui0XtPGZMvw8Ft2fU7IyhJGqQSkntJNFJW7fVeKxWhHUSa6VPKxK3lfpHlznYlWNI4tE2M7ndSEzmHeMXs80lThG7nNnibnOjExAPywx11nQq5zPEahhTJJ0Q7xTt8r1C1WywXkAzyt4voEnIoQx6DmvUEHeUK8NTF4U0jcGMa1F@DRM1EVjXFTj84gxKClwoyH3NkzTXJimOZOmmUgzbAHJJGNAkplIUpQCFs9dRdCzOsMF0hmDcOQOj7vENnwc1/Bw7vUmbafLdpalr9JlEMhpK13eU0Aop9vp8i45/HT5hByX6fLX4IjaVvpTuhw0CwTw4JUcT9FfiHB8N9PlHUW9lYZ4cniQrpYuh2UKME/4K3HklptXW2LW3w2tqpaV5UpllmGN8eHhYrYazSx9C/DPTwbmR9lD4FKVFVcIGAcgiU4j1mPwdKDb0HruteUp87qPcmCaEvaNyIYC4ZlqzKiCtWRE8iidSieFEScMQ8n4CE8gEOVmeT5FTJ8Zmd1HjkgdaigVcjJ94p5G@kBbofAGAMeNOL0oflBeSRS8AB9GJ0ZeROcMOUFyRBEuBlDnkIVMfZ@@I1NY1lOHm/PSj5fQrI0ACzEXgPBSIrQxmQ46HOqmlNjAHSQrCYXibJ8dj4Mf0Six9k5FI6kgWuaCYPIWOUPBEG/86l3ZicVD0hIiCAMbhSZvZWG/QLIYgyJZF9NUeeMDEmIyp02HOlpYbXeFk@C4uMlSX7GoGwri8iRJciXFJETW8LyGkTHkqUfzMniKw@cNX4OYY7yWRkEEsZhhKly@up@hv7tcfw8U6oAJUwnMU6znd6Wz6vWdvewU5b0o2dkCxMAs21XnKkdhChHLYXQQ08zvqmszKv7ICZR8nmiIfUrbD9gWjgnu4dv02ILjQi3Bu0p6XqJh9rK4mFGzGknvSguUFg1TEnh4xkNKo6zdTSvP@LwixhDso@Hx2QXsJQs4XniIjzLgTbGct3Jv5NDyqqht09F80cwFn3VwcZVYeBx/zBPEPa1fC5dogcfh@fHu4asX30Cnu7Gxoc5ORWCrhbhRPy7dOU0QDluKWTzUFrfv0dqJrusNl84ceXZJGXmAMmDQvA2vfqKNq0KWxeT5VNuFeBw2xlGB6zJqBkZCKqGqY2CXbQu@8rs8lRVDIAnUW@B3lkZrOGuEtQMndM7Pqfs6P8fFOefnohfDogmnkX6TYuJARymVXMNEepY/c14kDvtHfdp0FZjdxEmQfPUJnkJ3MAxih7FGztAOljigVYi2awYz@MqqjjaJg07oQ3TgUgyluIYD12IJD73hsRAazZ20oFKks8TVG7zjxx@4Dh1pT8cEk7KONw75gcGVyB451wYt/uCp0Fk9MYr4MqxgNsx1@PU7Po@L@0LJcBzwJsusC43meYpbMNC4tAf8pPNwwYevUiQimFZmAY9bPasPJJ1AjZ1jQ35pQ6Xp7tsXF1B98uJaWr6s5dSAqDm3k9sJTvBMsTdGzw6vNBErwehqImH9BXYqiSNYfVZcBx1qKwucjb7AWFwcw/CY1QItzSIo@G7AY4M7N7OxuEvKRJ19rupLyjmWKN@Eb3t49eyV4cT4S59PcUO0mKKkVh@bpwTmOuLkxjQe3Rie/imJY6CrNE2p4RK1gSKn5OBYUHRKA89CcZ3T@foJo2cG55UqeFJuWXrkkATCpWDM5ItsQNN1UHujeTY1XJvqsC/YalGie5pcsjJzAgAHn@JLYIcwiIr54Mv8hKSRv2jLX@CsovQohUKRVz@MH9RudNOBPlH1ZksCHa53FVOYvFkEL6XYC7YOfrMSZB1HI@tA4RxKlhQ5A2gzsipz1GH86ehimuQRF9GzmLI4U/dIsBqw/Oaz129bnucQmHTlQkXuu3g2Ll97XLljNTAtB8Y1h4nFwEh0fHVnRyx641d4ZuXXuGyrzBOhDkfDs6JR3lemBX5OD9Z40gMXV7MV2i3dSfROsoeRQzKWbOcuAqgbooqOYorWjH3hl@ELNGQDlMAmWuagEG/Ue2kjjuDiazx5o9CsxPohRY9TgwR2fJBHHeBnVqbLVR5DROqXoZNU5@lahUoiPhDnDxxa/i3nNJmiiqXKiCmJgpcm@ocLZiVaJR/IvTtuvzDy@mZhfYsWXTMnO8z2G1vN7IpZlZk1tA2n74@86/blhdu9Ag2DDT60xubk47eMldYY7kwpPuanC@jr1TwdILBBJ3BsFWhPSHD@B51RcSYzRtuR8TSRNGPhZqXKEh4rAJ8s/pTlykwtZSv9oBbyldf9xnqz6lQLlX7DaVacTEYdZqrDjJ5R0OOxrlZAUHNbTWPYpKWU@RX2MljviGdDo0HW7bAj1zG7btpndBF4fCKQdqEFDahvDOLt6QqGKq4X9@lgfTL6iYY460WXaE7FtN0AbjgZWChGw6WiPRfqL/48Gq2vVWbDMYePHuG65opQaOMZuJEGo1bPNkE8ET9RL8E1juWyWKlvMqy3ILvQz@aenBbowBQMrgShpjuYiMg2BzkP8rIdQ1lTsOtTsw@BDKBaUCfP8SYPD8A4CGdvApwBaurBVE4Vul9YTtg74eYKtYJLz9lSEBZsw0B4rDe0GeIcdEbaOgGPbSZAaWEyU8UyYPJt2LgSgfS7WpoHPfow6g9IPdA4vYIjeIHe@cCwvTCm5o/w7lKF6cgMOyAaSwAdt7in7wq00XjRBGWB1giaEcf8IL4jOmseCDYNvE8ZZCPOCCG@tktxHvGrHRXoMLm1i5Mh4lI2VFHUwDg8JS49SJcZGScq4EXdTyUW@gFCMa8LgvsQ3DeG3QXBXcQ98hcFexCMFz4uCLYhmC9UmR/uQjhXxBYADNH0BtX1fOieDw27p/BV1rg@@5YLbIVlMgFjwyrAeMHw8kjGZ2K9OlvipcMrW6J6QfukasUBsEorovHge1RbKBRPEVF4vYilyXnCbti9iQmLFbD4nFICsYvpqysJ/CxGALQ/EKVsNjxInJd2mNFE/dH4pV8QvA0y/9OnuygTFTFZ//RmUPt4CaFxNJZDzq0IDz9bMSpXHumjiDQ/jljPH5dugeYa5SNolMVIhPC2FbXrjg26JURVUcuJvHEcqrInkU/Db7JyKD0iPvJmcT8fizO1B4ep1CKzrBU5zYdz1cB6DzEN6JFbkbDAzVtGZYadfgidS0LXADrk5lQ9MxN1RrTSz83sw3KTAvqoURNvKlzQmqAa1gSBc8gzeLnGZQJHtpwuc3@8asxOIrMXIOObHM8BwXAbaMCeLRDjQZ9oOxpfKARyvlBcy5Ldn4PcRmwKhNVD@PQP0LiQcaLLHuHtK0mRxOawZgY8zDfyqzbd5KayxyX9/Mw1@Eqz9JM00shm6xPVuifQS5ZZgYW7aSrs9n459Ntx5iYqvoS@4yuLZUVQ6EFNfEgVvF3A6HsrWTILxSZLcBxJIMlwT5dEO0Pnd0rRfMd54BPYwnjbXqiBIVWVZDjSzBEGAaAox2Nlhc5Vi0Sn2BJ7PgyUm2ykheGlZ7xWgMpekeLiHIdz@9R5x33D/TzEkXgILi9EDdMLKLM7gW4LanAQTzPPsZg5k5Gf0KYvXLetBAqTUBgIQ7BsGoCyfI9RqFZx9TJKHpITSi@7EEuvg363Aj5Lwov6lQrd9B7oZ0jEygU1mwo2m5h@Y/t0Jx@FY28ESQVTQmhL4tKHlaf9ETpUgR7NjRRIfNwoRtuJhZynnjghHuQdw0G7HZ1xRkPrbRn9w4JAmBoMtKNNx1QGt3OsDHxjtdhyfBMfutgVW0OdOCx0MWqHYXpIzfa2jMlER3f8JrWUH/levmU7ecu5AqW6NZFSoXmrjPee5jbReou3lwppQsZyMghBNYGSwtQ0x7pWwttQ0fYg8Y2CZEDSJTxdgoz5PeuqDVo/X0Y/cP0x/U5gsFDQRoOhSyEiIdpQyD7Zn6JN7gWa2hUjBkHONuGJYBSc9OG@E263yulcQdLx5Aw1hqKBMUngymeyjOWHhAqzX6Mp@ZplmF0kAuveJz6cguKimnwr@UHR4wY4ZAXOKIKzx5f@DsiOh0mQduJP6B2yj@86OrgPWSKx3otxikT2WgzB68mxkqNZDuNvAwM44x@dnO7uHR9r4nRnPo2AUw/czIzrNmgXobjnXFhZcQoB93DyQnmEmUXcPL1qhJzkL/EIkxVswqZwjezkvMJNojwHOZ3eZrIRwqscnFhCc9DizUdeFsRS6wHoUci7KJoSi5YLogXAMVY8upcbhmni6tyXVt8FinesXg@I5rx4FLEDnciRIP1MmL7fwDSbIfE8PDcTnkuEazycExVBaWbXi4DKcSA5dRPB3TI5AsvOpFVlkOmDV7TlR3O9GN2Vu2B9DQZpdgRcC4uS18owYDsRkIuFvJtT@jxkKREnrOBheIOHi/pdFCUfUpmAfZpMH5@SKCCLFsaKdSRTtVRz7N4Tbn4MQ0jCMtzrwqNjeVO1441SGESEOMmBmMAr67HZ1qoRloweSBxqM3Jt@6msCZPUE2WaDG7wnmlYc9pIjEuUZoYYN6aeBNKh4KUYCsKJFY0FLbcWRJ6IyJMYWoRaCpKVgu3byQYOWZtu4lU0oX/Cn6CxJ4kL4FLzAx9xysc883wiLMkgErpL8nw2JaXJ0BtZ3FNk6o5eJEp7Mo1xvpB45eII1OyipAjTtPh0XccdOe2lUE7EBUUgKWb4HoYITkcAelB9FxUhBt5Kv8mvSF8afdAKe9aY1VGnNui8JSkxF4r3mPt4ihkeusn80WDQs8VmO3ZNs23iKKJiCSeGIowxpUGTDnDVDofPokvMXUIkjR0i5mub3xcuAvzRxQW//Jnh7ZIgWvFKd3uoSXVnwu@lxr1pRT4jKW6URwHcg2FfjAhecrz1hHd9a1JwAg/Paoe3b3FROc7K4aXT0KWVJelHI9u83PmSFQuFDb2wqsdYFpiqC9rqGl1vHahIQUCxoBcKJX1NknbcwYSvN1FMFXGt5RBhlr3Ajv4N1E28jN2xpDr0GASIx3X6lndltTVJOrbaZANujYgjWJXpenUn2HyPPqBb4SFEeEG6n@W3oEMNwyf2z/xAAZNWO2clnOIdWF7fHvKJYPfKxnvbw2ntjtvruddkiMYZZc4PjNS3hsCUFZUlSaLDAgQtpLvQHn7ghiEuqTZa7hUd7iHYAHqqjWci0fyshDtbEUM8MX7DbYwSSM/sGXYfq9McAnDrS8SBgADIWntkWnfSIBERn0lDcPt22zVHeFyCEZRMHqSfS20Fmrvl2SB9IwZTqVC0GO1QwKfPD07YyeH@6dv68R4D99Hx4ZuD3b1d9uwbdvp8j@0cHn1Dp9Ky54cvQLqcsPqrXfB9dXp88Oz16SF4yPUTiClTgFR/9Q3b@/HR8d7JCTs8Zgcvj14cADZAf1x/dXqwd5JlB692XryGzvrLLAMM7NXhKXtx8PLgFMBOD7OUahBNiuKxw332cu945zm81p8dvDg4/YZS3D84fYWJ7UNqdXZUPz492Hn9on7Mjl4fHx2e7DHMmLR7cLLzon7wcm9Xg/QhTbb3Zu/VKTt5Xn/xYiqjh29f7R0j8YlcPtsDKuvPXuxRSpTP3YPjvZ1TzFDk2gHmAYEvsuzkaG/nAB17P96D7NSPv8kKpCd7P3oNQBDIdusv619C5iTlHq5Auey8Pt57iUQDJ05ePzs5PTh9fbrHvjw83CVen@wdvznY2TupMOnF4Qkx7PXJXpbh/TaUNOAAbkE4uJ@9Pjkgvh28OoU@4/XR6cHhKxUK@S0wBqisQ9RdYvDhK55bYNLh8TeIFflABZBlb5/vgf8x8pS4VUcunADXdk7jYJAgMPE0nk32au/LFwdf7r3a2cPgQ0Tz9uBkT4UCOzhBAMCJ6b6tQ6KvKddYTkAXd0JllYKam6XiZAf7rL775gApF9BQA04ORG0htu08FzzX8NjcuVNud07gzc7yCVPI3Sf37Bzu7oHGxw/0kyP/19DpbCYn7xJh0NGEgfAqZkGprzpvW63RxbntdFwcmofR@Ax237/I4tmYKl4xdCbddZEenyinCKnU@fmb@jmMc0/Oz9XsQ2ImyLgvhtgafxeUKvLYc402DfMTtqU4o2qPxQE8WX4aRtzW8jg0Pqgsn29bIhouJEHEgZlInBQFyNooGWmFieGwWJI0xZy0FdExZtPGomB60/Xhx/kUvfC@IeYBwpmvW8jncQxLZOBxdCykHxKhk9rEcW20DsDuUJKab1mXF0ohnhwO@YWBSg3iEOwQhoEXinpP9JZ1MRU9Nx2fiMUVQKSsBGf0BGfn8GvB8U2wjIly0TzKmcJNe/RQA2ooIVAKVZ4ULS8Sq0@Uxzw6bvrmtkK1Ep7vQme0vaz/@OAtDuYKxbXKlP/z0J@3LVwKiAcOQn/XoHhNejxvcgBoYDYOv4Al9oRPqebzsTiglZE@GQLjAUJdBLq229CnYlfdtahbx2OL@BkO8fjQGXv2OE49iOEvj@svn73e3wfJidSubZY21iuSOAbJG/44y5/fYDp0jC9yF7ToaxvUNAqKtZId0Hv2Z04wjB25iKWHgHiAelBo5InXoofbmbmOwA8942YgzK6Pxz45ePKZjCc3eTLDRZPWkhTU17ktU1QAJZFVFXPTN8ak4RugKlEdMPnW5d6ESm2MP4g7bP5BEw8zJCqQqGJWfzCcQM2FwQXJPXk/WAVKYxta4oUgmhzU44ERrEHijEGZSUtjcYkkvYm6HStF0GuxoLG9UrFTTCBiaZqK4OQ8OgcTkjhy/aAFc08bfH4s6hs4vxEnNmIQnr9VH54AG/fDmLngREVucxYNQ2Bu1qpQRI8fhyltMzSkqoIobv9PnucXbw1ECl/QwKYQByuPQj6HIWSEfppW2Q2vqXjUCuKpiBor3qHmzsuOwFIJzqkR78Gxfozjik75I6/rMA0pAPkmAAnZmWDT78QPwv9fkSdz8G/DgBOwR9wiOWw7I@uBnCSsnFcweiWm2NfBirHYMrWIm3GvbyI0t/GC6YYZE8vwxnxiCVggSmcSeHzDz3lV5jAAKznaNeLtF09VoEbcNWDk9JTa7iM@0@85Zn@gBKekBl3FDN5mlnSubLBEDl9UPoVfYLHkXuChd09p8y3JDBxwgRRrTdgXvsxxZHSSOZjp/AoZPcJWTlUT2aAHLTyqTgXRtILGPxYrjKJeph2E3oIquvgE1nA6BA96TAj8YAYkECC09imeYcE2SLOGhM7NNy6/Jys/E704nmEOIpD6ZXZKq6d9o0NjZuyKxFJnXFONSSKeL9riIM2WNbzG7qLHsdMS7wgbU76gVeaYiLBFhmpEIHxVDbhOnex1SD2ZKbG@htS/di4dvDvE4iauAEJLHMsZ3xevsZcGndDZe1i@5SjxDLK1lkz/wKFl7yafr0TTHI3cIRUc6X/hRxwBjfMatUvohyIuGeYlespBHbWvc/YYHpRWTuQ8OGgSxgx0jPA8pf924YAA68rUGlgmnzmhEanMO7LqF4H6gi7edkPXN@gSduYqZAqIAx9cMCvUICQZ9SZcpDnb2oi@cK9DUUrR4tMyaE7X11rLGPUNp2P07d6EVp1@cLtO3ndG/kAbTPC@1KQ1kO5CATigfWixt7bTdq999gyaAxqSTl69PjlKGv5ilq8dbvli7CtIgz2jlKUZ9B3cyOK7nSEUjVVhE3EblReZe8hOKCwtZNaaoAfuFvKoAkG6/VAz/vLVa/al5Vge6INHtOaSvbBNywHxAcoUrcL0u1zSIPg@pn4iUmf7qLuQZafCLJuMOqFtTxIJCGxZrFoKNEUg2BNnXaNtfgJVPWYT1GYzHOWrHRiVuu5AbNZAoykqm9zE2Rn1shIeqP324PQ5Dsb5wJxsM9CtBbY@tCVy1anPjbWQGc9whhNgijRtvAGy77PdaIz2agBGaTE7aVDXxyuH2mj26/mQVbxKTEgB6kGgqVr2FZ7gS2a4h5QRrbMVZrOIbxWx6TUr7t8RoiNRelJUelk8yF3LstIWO7Ww7rKjnmHCCIudjDD66irogc9cf4igL@uMFYq6ruf0VTTRvj6pa9QQ8Bsc6ypJBy@PDo9PgZHi3KKgYoR9JjKfTlLlq7GAHTk8TxVy/x4FcgAPErP4npiHKnhwuIJc4TMWclmGsjcNNPdCDv2kOkwmWTTJux6d5oqbdaAKJZojpOpfo/DlUyOUUgx7ls6TFSfC8q4lpJO2WFKE90hbD@pVD@dD31Nk8gMBYI3JD2J5NDJoi7OIoEz6Vj@k3h4GvbvBAaTpg2hDhnFbKlSOdDaNWhJwT43jaVu4RsLHI536/pXpgWwxrqDK4RKWYMcS1BmSTWqYG6Nl92xoA0CX2XWxw@HiKigIMkHEj6mVqMTDAxCxQyJa5hwhBa2r7fZDUE6VJIU79IT/wJ@YLktdwDAbR1r@wLLadHzVaMDPZ8JwDVp5D3oOvnevHB3cJKUKtG7SA2GD5@SB7Bv1cEM/bsBs8TKXgtxArQr2fJ52cVjPEUGOTobUSPEYXWXOCDvLcJ5XpWLH@7UxroqMWLD7ElAMsjgpBVRBeVOFIBdVlyzdmEXlPb05EyPSCZH@IBmAuPisrpUMCNBj3oVzBoBX0mpIwNS@z4AYvmeJuxM2sOQL5hfXneKeNoXnETI3UUNm7tt4rjm3DbjswsVfBNYCjvE5QovmCGd2k@K9oTrgm4bUZyEBKjzVLQZZnIMzNxfn6nycOYFTTFYeOFe0nw5jUbXgueBHdLggH5ERUfa/dAPRS7v@ei6fYApzf9FzW3iYJkgKSA0fk2xUsHFvGoElGB0P5Ts7k4eAbgdZEqSLvU2B7sK2oX1YNbYdWCxqZw4vKBFQ5W2Jto8x6ruoOZETf0SLIqecOFEUtY6pI0WRPO4LshvRygKl8JHLLGqZuBInDi9STkbpJ6LoU1EEcckorUSUohRtH58qXYyBoh@fyZwFegmtSqISYNWwgApS3xjz0U2BNgOSmQbP8U5sXCw2RQVBwIbJwv2FCN6UonMzEtP2PI3glZbg0YpveVmmc0gLyUOoxsHSPRIDBJUIn9DZLI4iMqQKNtBLeCaHGhAj8rVNUZyYpAozzAOkRLY93KulxFNRyyw1MPisIUL52LHFk24QD3CWXoa/FaaIBHJxYjkQnnUgRCEwns7DaMBQlhdLIAcLUtQz01tMwEEJSlx@05Ix3g0oSqJdBZI7xMmdM7IbUKE/R0cpSXxTtg96HffFHiUmGk5Q4cOz5YWSZ41heEZzzISC@p/QYi08@UETofQQxDeilJtBr5HMxULo6a5kHkysVwm5cBdwwOyQTwuBF/c2xDq0IaC84@Ax1r1AI7FgXdAFp33OMtJS7CHtRXdNm0uoJNtiQpfHzc4RwMkiD4jLTuVKip0vI3I43Y1IiZ4zUUmU2BvencO@4KcLc0SqlIiF/F9U4LjcMd6wF8LpHE4U@6IaEeIKyv2uahECB@V@V7XgwLFiv7taBAdMh6yl@NP1IlESnAW4KFGMGMimFJdBQcA4DjWegiKCJs34ATNWT5lDbUyqClunNKMqhSwS58kl06DHmBeMuLYsWR2BeY2wNJpRbqGPMy@tdnhMhsh9OESqyckugZfm9OlQmOkgBSqjpor3mIQRQGJzI5gYM/f52k06ZijNByw0BsWjVC@6yd29CbRBr1JQZxXK4EiliPjtucTnZo@2ioZY5dlLe8LVZYJqXPDkem2ElqU5M77SPVRlYlQlcxcroSSLF2DKPQhT7gGY8jFMomGvQn9JzpSHhwdb96E4O5vFQY93MJASOEDStm00YuM4@NqY3IdzCZStFK2pM/iqsjBCpCffh@PJNA46rL0bzsYJz66BVrePludOH5W2kLPJujKHopCq1CxZWSSLpDaNdwVcoCrR2Fa7bHXtcCSQur@k@ZkSIjIuJe6Gk0Cp5FFHIbKo/esL@JeNFWuyPXDCE2YY0Jalz2wOGjKCW5j4VrEwQkyQJcehIiDJiLtDp4UfjVanT5rAU@gXRlPvzclTbvCJGZ10yBqXWIkaFwzhIuEU9FaBfJs3PLs3/dTc9AfuAHSczlwCCL6PdnxulJoS6ZFqOjW0flBfNrc/m81XXG@bOjDu4Y388UzWi5B13JgOjdqxrkXvfxdmkZegBH4LTb4R1JEFRH4xl0icaDeEcYs5o37L8qSHNHUeQ8MHHyMtrrmSlEqxuglDZnFwEV0bRWcqWyJJVIOxIvhsNMD5Gp8v7sTGjTYyi1fgaVi81J6gNRmTIBtt3zIccZKR6DAvPJy/CGGzeKY6bu6iFGzHBEb7Vsz8@Z5fFNK2RAiuSL6DrZX5ZY@1GtMUVGSjlARZXNdUJskxLfddoOCEWg1BlacVlaDu4GToCtfMhb4Eirk63wT2EO3pLoUIKvGiJMWAdwr13XW0vJiZo0HIyrBoHsDKeepWaOV@gLo1eai69V@Bk9MFKsXcQnsQHWz5XqE2PcinW3KD07L7c45ueXO6v5848KQ1CUYFfcsrFQoFPARn5ko8nKDAWWLbzSeh82gTzw@uv/LetPIYNXkJ3tw78JAGAEVonJrAeoJTEyPob2KncqE9x8FdOR98DslP4GkzWsZph4vb35xS5SOUyDyrzN5jBjF/71lwVTUojnzIILAE680gNqqhV3KwTA7Ygx4dPFEnXJJGyGjcLHYt4MRHtXYjPRL3QpKdD@/wUW@ibYjyc6vXc7Psrev12ksy3x2ajLC/H49Q4CC4lJA3Hp/ulMgy68ruxe7VQJDYPfD8Yia8dJdbP2kvk2cNcCZNwX7s2LrYGw8UufFOhooJWc5gNjNMbuL2ngsZuiiZptDvR8uPMQOyHwTdNwaKSXyaBoY@UOylilxA0SrevMlXB6M9ZQeyjIs5lASIys@F4Ty7HxqZOp9c7YNrOwpkHYMl3C5HW7@peCknC8BD5spnY72DPCxwHIImPDfxYTFuK3jo1G//Qes2Wg5wcyPZeMMtsbHzxuL5CIzx2LLY1bDTgebFLfG14KixAB2JypxOqxSQNaJgPevbEegzSrrji2PvcKnNycQxE4Q0is0sE4fjVX63PEpBCxTND/iJyya@zkGz3h/R5SqRPCMzHC6gmJU7GOEcI0jSF2b122ulXq@z5UEmw@r1Z@DI5Vj9WZ3tosezZ2wX3p/h@@NqsVSq8JVzu@oNeD4LPG/ZM8BBXRBe5LYLrxBG9zPhUAqLeDlfXc5Wls@r27WKn2/UnzXz@Qtw/d3v//Tv/umf5Ovi5Xt8eUYvjXchkKZp@WXzZvnxbQXfG7vN9HKrsTxopi8qWMtQ3L/2fKNnxLaJaeY/yGW6wc55U2Wg0arVapqlP33irrNh5PQiJ958EEU3eoOuQdEZYahV0/X048fg2q6mf5JW8eSO/6@9q3tu4ojhz/FfsdgDtg87joHyWZiBPvHQdgb65jDx5XIOnnHsG59TSBn3b6/0k7S7dz5IwlAKHR5gnLvbL61W@kmr1erz1D//i567Psty7BeDtNg@fv76l5cv48uF/KWlM0aavOGeanDafFnOaVDTju2eDyduf9@9Gbqp7x4HdB/Jh9Uuui5HjEpn/tZO2ugQfY8oVTQs4acIMJK4J4lGOytPEV5kAUp4h2AwLnTz5LGEzqGO2yTw@Psncii1J8uNh0/d5Vi3p8PJ@P5Pb4adTgctIzr3KIOYQ2tFuN84i4JlEekmGfUKWjI0dq6NuzxxVCETo9O5mVE/bmWax2GJCyV5wMhX2O10o9QYjrqUy1WEe/7@Xge0oSfLWMOid6TMz3HcmrHBxVUD96gD/tp098HhSt@23FR7Ed0gGN0ezBlP6lfL@wSd4XJ53C1vFWa1TAz1CoV4ZN2Dg57qGO1vghu7TDXVK37cPdtZ0hP3q8XF6YJv3MShifIdSSeifF8na7G0rIjcgpQ8zme88SkrWiYsHNoDMMz5LOwy490FTkK64My7AvjsrmVCkLQeGOFoHo4Zn/nuLZZyVGA1o5@k8DkhotwpDTa8jeROwlC8qYYUMVLe5EBSEHYt5EumKv0dwmzBHhzkrQEae7sBl0VfS2JDTzmtmHBE3/iN3QDQ15XUxlrxITuEKs/YBGWnCBGFv9xHwloSDRduulhOm@6aRpQimpRm7kgkMkks38xcN17RnBz6bfdlNJzedplulLzFqiznGqii04QoHDklvKZaD7staUy5Jb6NOyn8iorHZ6yUvyc@Zz@Y5Byh1mmQygWVDzl4kyMPJS6uU4nHxZXsLHKP8808k6NS0voNk8UF0oHwU8mb8tGGyHiQcFCbYLRw6PQUqkaCYqpDPaATn0rm9f/WQ@8UNLMQI@mvZW0pJp45/OwcBiKFGj0noIIqUbSPcE4pBfcqjLnIT@ebSpmBHLrW86Uyiq2Rnhf5FBGPEXVrlOXYILsO24uEqdLbgrBZ8No7ErQPJbq6mfdsMKzVJBbLl5QhIXHGw13@8PLIuhP3mlYwkY@X76A6Q1CurOvmpfCxzElgVRdm4ZMtoHLtosiLBCf5UYFKizpNhhO@FLhGDRKntWUQpPBBpfqIgZm5Y00OGVUjr0yXQIId4W38Yj3dNlxy/2@2W5nK4zWnmqXFR18xH5CODsHkx/TFMgvoxlfZuALf5QbUWfzOcX5pfb4g5C9B6qpR4nvkQ6O@H7WmbOg6w0MgpcISlk268VzWitp4Q@k31dLDruRu@GAZHHoR0in6mthB3@6JMidtavVKaobegf25tRwSmoLBR6bb7CjJoV7TGZOHY91ZmofJ2TaxhtnwJuVtzIosODQmrhx1IfeQfhfH@zcQaQsXzvPzzerl5stjevju0Jv5zD/EXfWEC1KCwQoR0v5If9HPCe69/kJmAcuBOQkCOamSljn9brUEeaiF2f61PH2xet87GBy2D9uD8f1H/TbsZI/DOllJllEnyzmies1WQq62J2lijZD7MxcRvj6en5wQ4tAbF6iotuZfHWm1E/aQf/DirhxC1bYhxPN2JMvLIU0iHiit8btYp6dnKX7@tvpjnV68JCWEP39fyny@5vpekTLim1fx5pWs0ecnBDXaW7aTA09caYhwmaeEfLINoMEml1QJHi40ECDfIYC06cdfVgcbkSEev/guPHqG3qRJnQpCKSU2fCo5AacwAfh4AtlpR/KMeFNNmBL57OQnXolBUAeQ/MJO8kRPpYRA/YV7xmUqKf1CRjUwXg@tSamBWxCDHpjJ9emhrOTk49T3vpyqYbPJ3h6dnS82cx3ZzrBsXFxo4IQU53wtiQ6TswhyNrz5Uz4A9TNeIr2yYXR2GdZpF42D653MaZUGWwaCKlBBjTCrJbIfjdwYP9yOATSoqSIZ3O/cA38cbJ98Ym4E3T8zU4MTrHMSt2g6MF6meWRuSMZBr2edH/WNivHB/SCicDeSgmWyiOZtPMc8w5wCHsLET@7XsNm/ZyNXnjDJjgKVzC7VMGqRYcHWx/nhgTsYYrcgtmqJU1C4XJ1ZtKWaE5HxGt0NTSuIT5D/1wbrJZZbBf1FpLLzmTF2uVFZaBVwaAfjInJ6EAPNHM8CxhqDkRhJQOQUmgFN6NyOklayrm8QG2KU0JfS5zrINsTkR9og3qiKHeU58DBi51Xf0JtHQPiUeOrEhKpqt6DYdDOYvXpBg1lfq5gyhuwuKNCAWRuMcM8GlxIq3yXU@PMIJf1qopO8@WJkqhKgSqVtq9XEvl506IHReK37XAE7cgmEu@GBcK2OBqCLfc2oY/XqaAIN2T8yMJy456ckFqtYWKIG0vBMrB4xIMtabijviJMjNefr/DEhYkJXLfpHkJelFM7HVTwgBFlHLf8RMkEwNUBv743Q3GRu1Om3dGd2JKFEvfGDcR@NXKGlVuXejGvDexGDvBUz20lzwQoFkCNxR5oq5HLtB133Ebd0ZXyNLmmSyMEpLeI5KQo@snuZl3rUsRu2HFXv@u4zHdTwldwRHcR@nlGntUddEKTBAVvUGErfVgdvmdMwCjsyI@7ckPhD7ENzdH9L/m@jcYmU/J4DPEA4MHTA@Ixr1QlWhIBQQizQ7s2yS6T2B@YbWwlQDXARpK1wsmnwsarqRoeQnxVo6dJ8ioDakVex0WtqHiLXaSzmenK@N11g6yjP2BHuvVRlP/IHq9th1LVs0dwtSYniq6yIq3g4t2457Rtc1jWM0WjoVwgl/agQ43ApwrnOuiSE@CEIryqFlolHfUWj/0E@0C/C6rzVDERYvAYcEjw0o0D386WnfDN1UPRT9OEBna5qqQRAE7m/zpI8ht60rkvQOj0vYVI49L4fLr3WTFyVVX2i9GZeFF38YCy6ONY9F@WIvQ2sfSQfv2T0QQqZoH9cEqdZ2hP9CzcF/ScMyvd2pRufLoykfbmRyNF@CPIoN/vlBurrSdh@ZDtOdFJ6ckLq@JxP419sqAo@iI@b6iI6S6ESJsX1FKYZ6dK8ikIyMbkrdctMSwe7zMEwi8xfyz8GSs00YdMeVYfwIuRs4a2rVSYZwDgIkJ0DiCuFXTsWs4gNIik44T81kcreTPKRz3QlywhccqTN6hi0PxiEYKwX63RzJYgVtuTkdLtbcjZYvmugxoflfovv3LwuJLsKLkuujMs6CXzaSYBnSacgbHH3M@v4ujgtOGipnrbveZsXKhz4MDmIxDRBi4tB7MxXqRVvuX0@7PsBX75VxZB88/Al8eTPqiAmCSAmawQx4QMtlbHjDeX89xAPtGyXsJAThT3S3qraHq0ba2/V2F6Zc4ZhF77Twis0y48bmt28W2kJz6jaIPyPjQ2xrJU1PW3r2p663u6ClvkOavjuDzX8f1bD/wA)

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001663 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 10191 bytes)

## Bitwise

This is another language I found by stumbling through Tio until I found a language that ignored unrecognized commands. The main code is on line… IDK one million…? Something close to that. Anyways, this is that:

```
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
```

Here we’re outputting ascii values 49, 56, and 50 to hit 182 on the output. I should note that I first attempted modifying the Hello, World! example in Tio, but it had a Mov command which gave Grass fits. This version ended up being a better golf anyways, so win-win.

### Cubix

The only languages to break with this addition were the usual suspects: Cubix and Incident. Incident was easy with a new token in the northern ballast, but Cubix was not as simple.

This answer tipped the Cube into the next size up, so I had to move the answer capsule to a new location, and as fate would have it we ended up in a forest of BF derivatives. Luckily, this line (the Minimal 2D line) had a string of white space to allow Minimal 2D to catch it’s downward IP with an `L`, so I just displaced the whitespace with a `[4O6O@]` to house the Cubix answer. Of course this was in the middle of what looks like a BF multiplication loop for Agony (I think), so I had to bookend the Cubix capsule like so `>[4O6O@]<`. This tells whatever BF-like MP is involved to point at a memory cell set to zero and bounce over the capsule rather than traverse and then return to the cell that was involved in multiplication.

Bingo Boingo… we have #182.

Good Luck

Comment: I started to wonder, how long until this hits the answer size limit? Vim tells me this is over 47 Kb long. But then I find that [supposedly the limit is 30 Kb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/knowing-your-limits-what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-question-title-post-image) (although not entirely hard), so now I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen our limit is a bit more than double that. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12956/69655

Answer (score 7):

## 193. [LOWER](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/LOWER), 9440 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1dbyNLlhj4LHr/wb6EkrpFUvxMUqRIUWQVJVElVakklT5KVSXpspJkkkwpmZmVmZTIUumiZ7zodXv8YI9nB2PP2t0z3sXOg4EdLPZhDQ@wwPrVGPg33HlaDBbof9B7zonIZPJDqqrb3V4vYEpkxseJExEnTpw4ceIjm4rT@81vwvhhh6Y@6uqmy1zVcVnb1m5UO8U2RuyZojn5bC4UQqia3R30VcN11kJhJjOmGS2tDX7mmteqoX1SbQjPMmbZZtdW@sztKS5TnZZiqQ4zB641cJnZmZ8sx1i9b15pSUzZ14wugLmqbdmqS/ErjJ0autJvtpWpmPxUhpYN8Q7bUvXP/c8ua5n9vmK0HYAsMPbKtB0V4Vuq45iYfJWxYV1tTSEtAqhia@Zebf/5VFSJsedQRMXS1SFTmo5rKy1XMw2kSYYd758eH06lkGX25mR7ezo0y14mTYNtD1rX01E5dmo7iq5M419htYFr7rrT4XlW66qGwrKpUio7HVlgG7Yyk2SV2arS7mi6moIGYUnWU3VLtRmGsI5ps10okl7MFDON2jhlqoVpi@PIabQlpudy7lR9shkgvGn3VANKmJmOlP3IqYisH9HWKAPFHrGo0zNt4CObDRy1zW5Nuw3MZeijWALSs@En1lQctbCCCHI@gmvDvDWAiVwTmrY5clVmmEaSEiPgCpP3GtOMlc1jaO1gdzq8wLJ702GrwGit685sW2aL7Mi0RtOhJfZK25vHzrkM7wibZhtaYypOZocKBFE2k4TPZSd7QQtaFzozu3KgYG2VOYZmWarLI4FXVJuiITXTNeOad/BD22wPWtj53J4KeWOHRX5wQi1IVWWWEBMpdLAwcRAHgxIcm301WF6HGSo0kGOpLa2jtThjqUNXNRwospNiGlTiVtN11lZ1SDDG3kowx8TmHQc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjLctiPApqAUXazhSZitRjnyBe7zlsaPWZo/Uh2m2ZnY6qsk@q1YPkobYZYvBpWVPV8n1LKsAYqkca1QKBgKQxkdJAJ49Ct7YCpLUdQQNX6wNhNTfiMFVxNBSokMRRjTZR1fJFrcmUCZZnNxp0eKj6wCbcjmpTlyO80D1tFVAqfjNHb23NdanXsBo7VBWbndiqGpsUuxNZQmYm5uBiRVLUqOvrkfrBdgQal6dIKRY0pp07ef0ipLBUhS01yvCtSFI5VN/fYndLF@jmUhYYwLKjSoxVfmBO@uJChe9Qbqa79n0IsIaAKjpLm5abVpIWFDDpQgHTCjrRlbzJpiw9kDFbn2qLAMtxqDa0Bggf9iZBNWsNbBtHkjFRlWuotG4aXaAnVNYeGEgPgxUy0AQtEwaCBFNvgGogeamNQC4ghU96GjSag00S6Fh8PCSCwogIbCwo6uXrmPqA4CCl4yIvA1UgKWLc7bA3rKNoOiaBeETFS22rzkB3Mc3AaGPLw3intlPMKwZ1WBv4@AayUwApBQDr9wP9kgoFwNAQJlUVo378p3/e7nYBT63VAtkm2PUNa5stGrkVKiwMhwwZFgSqTsUCuATmzpNDBjeKrrVJQCjGSGRBhaBcb82B3mYmZGjfatBLe8oN9GzoXC1X5UzOB/sE6yvXXJponHOh4n2lCQ1LGVDeVO0ke7YJrdRSQ2HimWR/4HaKLGnVWcRJfx99uhZ9unihQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9I619Yuy1PJg1kCmltEg91VjbZiUghEDnWKm3QfpHkKBoc3SeEKxJlOA0mO0alAMBJmOuyGB4RJ2UG@NJFBQA6lHF1VrWgmJcdQTCDc3HpjxLyaTuEQFV7TLuORcCQerDphgJpOVBQ764lmotjSrR4OWkAUw7FgJLCRd1swUqNkdDQXNM4EaxJf0ygCkoVk4q0asVUc0n0@oi7JuxymT6KgFBjGXWiyJ6vtQEcGIQB92XVmpLFu3kKGVCYcZkB0GJip0oWmgcS8IjVeEZ4ThUxWiSsagK2psmKyqUEnwO4GMl3wfKBuAJ7LchjAxjtJQPb0lRFgafFhddxhmNaBvtQH8QDaUEtFmQPCR@UDCmYyoP7ngI6N2nYmmc3nJ/vYTBdz7XQt@R6E9Kf0oz0JKx/sTChoWEe9ZbpidAdKV@WaGFNaLdVyhaCCmjguiKLp8YYCk2LwTDm90NKz6bxpEPFUi3EeKOR564mhUEHpIhT9JKgzKlPEVAU0RxvEkj6azh0AbqYylz4gyEQBPkgPFMHTAIDJ1KHaGrgg1YCBb3taqwc8i6UzuFzkg9B09hAUzB0ke7LjZ42FkatPsqFU2g/CYjyIIoktOosHBldEVZ0IoMYPBjyOWXH6cxCbfhFhIAiEptJKCnjvCzj7pmHOQQqE9NEiyGQMbwfQxI5RoYSBy1O7qLP6WqbfRNBmOBFoI//1XNdy1mCc0NzeoJkCTkmf2KNd98BAZkm79khzTe5u6mYTxLID/TPt5ZBuDZracKpCFOa34ZUTugEFrOOwCozcHwfAddFIxwGBSeGbCByIkkhwEwr@KwEgAaWAUNGOQ6J4G4TK8choRaUUdaUUdDopwSTsuBJMdyRM5dNl0@yjFGJnpBigpgfTPs3AuYKQ@STylblDnS/7Sa@LRFJXpmZE7yKLi4uRtUgVJPvi4lNwraPrKbri4HpKriS5EC6FLkqRIBfGnlMKDLuM3J97mIexS2y2IY5KnzQrqpyvreUuE8q5LJ5ZfMZA1IFkA@gkPgBPJFapoDMWk6q3UNFUszNZ@02UzsctW7MEEV4oNwr3CyrkiAxa38JppK2WcZB9nCb9ig2jICitrV7UjlycZy4uL@4u2vGL@0gCU8fKSqUJlYL8ov1U1zYHMFzGzlfWkvJlLHaeg0GyWYlkIsvRaDGpQ0ZKLPZdMRZXOLWjERWkdvTiIgJEFfQ5b/VswjdMZGMxn1RQDhyYQSeMRlJ3Rci/GbuMxSOQNhZJwBSjEokAZVpIBIcqjZw5QaCDo5ecMJvxeIjY0LSv8Tsj9iEsBRMsnnwb@HfzeHLa278G6cpajo6qSNLm2gh408s8sE0PX@NaY7uksRow3EINYLRt@zMjnI0bA9KfSbk1gxnRdBAhKAzHHpSr2gQMIu5oQ5ggQL8feYoQjt@oC23ChNPU1dQZqSYSg46D0141NVcbOuTDSqrljHkA9B5wWrrSgo49ie5CYheAEPg8nZ4fEyvPIJ5WlWhW86U6wsDSUgykX1sjrX2gOT0kL2hWOJWwO0BVVNlBN1CJarusBWN@FyitDjWX6/DAR8eYZEdxojHUGmtc60JlDzUGLJRnA6Dh3GzBfEcFzQFj@eSR1Y0bzTYNJHKqDqiB4cvYBlPI55EX2KhW281uPUzfeciBYjPBcoC2QazTxG05LZY2TN3smmwZAJA1UynO2LsGmkpA53Nheskc7RMRqNY1jdEUD6o43DuoI8qFnK99KwiZJvjUFcgaNr/SY4AH6ny8@74OI4Scz2Sg/J4vQx@/kgEs03XEwBYbAwiTrY58gy35XrV6owmDEvIHn0UCP5kq75h8Xq/AgAqlEj38EyUNdnIeAv3ci2p7rnl1r5OGhKaM4CxjovagDEI/FdXh3QZqGJ4KxlCPFBNIZxp83L7bIDtPegM1pLZ6JpMuQMPIVlm6rd6kUeBIIOh6oConISvVJmXMTyZMyCHXHIBW11Z1ra@5u2Tu0g1UXcbDsheLVrsxgkNNdUNivjEWr2iSGstao8vh60MckJyQSk@2f7BVbxzWTnYqUnrg2GldawIHt9VGHxRPXXUkNv0JsyMVkIn0n671I9N0K7y5rnX2xU8Y03jJ97Yae7sbR7Wjd7wQhMbR@gNdwaKsLU0BYPJjivZ6VcAO2LHNvq@RO6IhlnJIenXC5o/TUxG7grEDYfEPhBcwvI9W/FQr1G21WNLkXj9QAK4iIFr2aQzrxuMISZZ@P1BAFgklWvtTdtMLLGGgb@efsICP0c2LfziRwHwnZ@4RuWMMHCtQsztZpvAbt9PBUdsPzlLwdRJZXR8H5yiYrxNMWugFWWai5gL7@FYIH19fmItvJmousI8vz/HhusR8dFMx80B9ZAVChusYc3FNRcwB9DGtEqbg2sc4rkhxDy18iLzmRj@YyMddIty4ODJGRUslIsgDzHLu6POFC6eBNtIxj2TliViM4ssdLNmGyck6giC/fMaFEAgCLc6x2il36I5R5IIokqBz8GUQP54zgqw3lAb0ynFpvZBAFEvqIMDkwjhx3k9sTiU1tXGwD87bNas3QAQMAl3aCwlG@Yl4E3rrLcFOkeUtaJvWKNCX77Kc@H1NiJNA78pxcpMcQu3Inojk1La8NZeJON4t@TpL44ob6xpimQXbhQvCExh690xQmPY0h1Y/g5Ix5Cv2FyHJm51MqOHSOCY7thKy5M1886YUREQyG8TqtYmT4rGrkUnJecTio@hf67MpO6Bb0s8E6EyhZmP4WNFvduhnDsCasJzBsIhLQUiVF2j9R@OeCZq@ektgZAMgZEAtzVDSR/RAa8C88kzaNSYK01Q7A1CC0zBJQ/cXwJKlIkF2mk3tIVCgCxbde84BswfNeWSD3tqbMX2xCcK7A9vV1bZ4/seftaEBZpunp4xI8fcdDaAb8UbnwdYSSdFDP/NblmCuBrqmEBnI9SWULQVXGxTdd8xHjRoMSyZ7it1H/Vo0LjAn/kDveoTPeMltVR@0Ve85PxMi8aSBjac2tD7VCJ44QaTp8APJp8yDPD1NsXRTaRMWPhHS1HFr83ZRh3xKENC0QRZ9RTk9Kx4bL5u5vYE74L@4UvaldtUs/M6nytokk2XySlNW06ajNDX1ET6wletB20xa112qNBat8BC3806ERqdkR1euubOBzvkE4FW0tW5Xtb3nQ2C3PdDtaVKSvqXHI6ziaVaMdGXlMZy2zn8fAvH2qviOh@mk6fTzLQxJLNKCXoOkxeXwZIBM2hRhdaU5wslZ79s5CzMklRUET6UVj2dyOMb6ax/jhXfLejg9DsyUvlSan5ovxHOSzJuypPkCfJIbpqjOYkn@C70eRi6tr@jJbDvgfFCIe0bPsWsOKM3Uky1dcYCZXNEc6g00H/08xuA4GLWQrcauR9h7XBxvCeyh1ZRxGgs0EV1zLN7jhOchaTpthx6jwR0R9DNOir5Z@rZJGXZ6Sd81XyCYLRdXNB7gt68QcHwxAZdrAgyUMh@iXcu8xe@DKkbPvFH57/xB79PcUn2FqErqxBlaa07ydutL7Ipr4vQzn4rXc0vltvS54cJyPzkd@FqGdjTddGBejr@PEQI0bMfhv/NZOUgzTTGSZGAOuucnE4WyWEoY1B5oSUXvmnqh2E0r8PNgcw/sDop/8fxaseeLLVn@stjytCPTkMXzQXl/nbavv8QJZIW2cbUq4HxksJ0nu8Qqx8MVhDkELkHPr9x2pkgpU2luJHmoAexW71YZec@fMKQ8RF1vSLFGpFuD8ocJSkVwuDbXt39KbiuP59b@OoE0g3b1S5UINO61roJ4pt@ZJmXZjPyNKeRM5uvFU0cfqAN1rpZ30LxScRMiN@fizgVF1/ky6MnuwTcWKiOqsSTMiWkgHhoTfahPYub4VaXGwRt9jwoYRdegk39RxZkr7yxQyC2cbB@C4xAdswm7xsCaaNwA7Y4GxtHjlOtZXs822xOFxJhvlUjFLytSEzq7o9L3If2@3jdhfmz2QWEwvqL9BVKyfPDfCcQUMlYzJgwkc7P3l7RBoQXFA1pUu3aSaBv/OqGTfWhST8ClEkzbDNUd4e9DlJ4nRJumqX9Ly4AsbWu02VhP4vbSL7XQjJIjdjewsfnCQVNIs/OQ4YKPM2KGCdTD2bT7yPw5aI56ZEo4Y1p/ZLQKGNq/NMmEkZosQ47d8twPMeQRdmo5VUytPsqOXAc1m6qu8MewsPIYvlIq9yg@X@sQyi0tzOBiDl@@Ga9/hadEjzUCYmltmKD01L5K3kc0e6V9NXC8x4NAQxO/c6JTaVqMeCCdpUFfN/B3YqkooA25pgFTKlexuyrOSXRcwxShD8lXb41jLnF3@0pX5WcRHhMdY9MEbnvjM7mxc76RYo3vRGlBMr5Q/zgrQMe5VkeO95yL8NWoBe056D@KbV4fb6EF9IudOpWeu7TzBXXP6Jk9o6f2bOocvu@h7gEc6fJTJI9VAsrfU5xr3OdH8mg8l@s5Qerqpq5/DXVRHnLpaJrzjbN13KPfhqTfhHekNCFCPL5ox4Mhm4hEY/dDfaenDmBkckzXtNQk@R4C1dHiw3/n25t3DyIOO9NUu803KaD5T3G1pq6yWw2KcOUEV8bnW5OauqngVtJHlHegjPf8GvtUy7S/aPzoKqZrWfRoWPrAoR@y8yY78w2Ya2ybSvo1zKC5fH8IZ1m1azZbPe1LRWqqimto12nPkMO9j85LhTCmmmssuYXBKV0DWtmjFDJBJRh/jI/dh8a/wDLO3NpvDmx79GXBMLnq79tb@SoBOh7KXyzQzommIR83QHkbfR5ZqhDruQ9yEynQqCwn1QxoJfKD9p@JvV5CetHC4gNKz1S9qTCBtbRvsV@KDQFkydMCmxogfJ7x4iFBuCPkG8wKozuDrhP7MuP22qBT4c9chLUuHqviq0mObt4GrM3Q9RVDPOaOyv7K42MLI/lHV0bmkTmVFmugSXXwoL1L1yyH/7JkJzu3eLOL@rNQo/mzX9FkbbXDf7@k6fVNGzfAg0qRbNmq00IzOEpjLiW5CDLMLkjlpM7GwB7s3OLP7iGYp6tMjnjJt/tqV8ENcXsa7o3TndlBEDBPbyf4GsSvB4qjvR6YrjoX5/S2gq9B@Urpaq2diRbwEHrUFbun@GOiU2DQbEPc9jSH9iF7jvkdibMYrdDPRk5b2v3zcI8bRgJ6ktgOypK7zNs26jvQ1o/xyty8JrVQsTj/oODTXDKgiufces7fgvGYVeF20LcGjnjMz72PpwqCduT@NYU7txpIxeRHEMKsp@jufFtzwJgK@pUYGcfOh7Tu95pudtn7YoaBOgYCD5XwBxhrA8bpQ8WFHmA487RAmh1lU3k8YPulsW96eROtF0mu9jgfgTXUHEtqhuY@bqlxXQVmSt4Tq8iVMTxHk97D39SzWQx8X8QRHczzj3A4CbHzEMI0W5wfc1LeIc0w7dKkAx3eBn8WxmMmAxyAXNNOMYKLRpV4PBYL8URowu8aAOZB0TE5PELDT@A5TNccl2C1Djs/Z0t3w7XMmnzPKkxak9jlJceKHzrQUR9adMbtiCc/X1IuK0uRZDKyFLkw1lgm4oOrOrDuXHBlAraj0YOXd0wCZih8Ly66vRqX@REhp0fH70Bta4P6d2qQVQZVSX7QhZ@iOsG9A//hr9riVCLMER3Qm2DoAILgoVyzr/bM26c8X5F7zbIUPNWIOEDS6PyMTXKzxqALgJ7IDyOat@x0@6QojjiJE8DgOeR6hF8K3rhoqcANyi5vPF4af7OpyNhP5VWqZeqDvgGaedvtOSl2rNHe44E93kQILgQzXBunJ@0E22VtFVdoaUs5zch107ymsyFYkv/wV/xgF20sFxt@vezpQGcgR9w/LtNpqlbLHECpPSSfVNsUIFEkMsidAdq6oHupPDyG263pxBlwZNI7b0XZ8ENXm7VjlqyzCB5uxmMcZa0TXaodPX9znrms/MD6afU//iwduxOEk75LlgqOlGAeSPkeGSsYnYfocWyESUtDiWfo77rXxK77W94eQCKFMxluvPd4zDQt0WvozCwdEfW5UdzdEEU3tbN38KpPx22JYdVbOnhFu10NlMd4jtVwoIOBN0aoea@rLEUH3CSTPHZZHjLEw2sKuPgBXdqHjoeIMMnSkH1mPWSyZAv3RoOPE1LHc2v9yoa3ZScX3FiV3lKbA9pNcJNNZXMVqs5So7JeJZettk08P3r@/cUwm0leDFfrl2nHI@rFxfC7TPYtUN2E2eLSkzT2vPr@1t1Sqpr5/NlRRkyS7iNlvhEMxMTS3eHuYf34pHZyegytcO@Jn23T7itjWYNcRLude6ZOJ3OBLramOt8gf3wfgEejbElh63jnRCwWCm7kJVBBaykpLXFnQDRNpP5C8nnpHTUQPwsgZFpHYx5H7cJAhG0IzIZUw8oPLDxfzERacUaSuExDGY8dyCcMbrebI0uJVBKrALGSQKyvJBV7uLJPedjXUOyLWB4n29O5IEgxP79zP55XcS4J7n8n9bZgoPzt682xPF5vgnmk3gDqh3pptmu7e6dH9clkwGP0JKlbKeXFDnYunLGncWuOdyiUDvuIhGjOqkhMogTcKwYzulCkqbq3KlRLCMdWnycmDqXyS6ExYwJlKngry2WZ0yIapRKgDlLGak1tsO9ow0ARvTE6gO6OV9EXAtuSj9oreEoSmMN0Q0YKP141EKsgl9f1DkmIC3kdcYLqT8LrcVg1HKNBM6ZUDwxV/qjjMPgPjEqeK3vJhkwMZ/IlS7IsfHUVZoU9HzZW5mMUW@KEkJZ42SW/vHg7A5SpfaXQLJI2e4kzBDBK64qFR8EF9D7M3NbYx4FJB5Y8YeLrF7c4R1H4RSTUtC0Fa0MHoQwXj3V74xbh290@rqB2xlUzku9BnhsYOFABUOBakPoQph/AbB2S9fyCAU5yU5xl94ZKMjM64uyqryU47EZzyAyJjdBBHUcHSYm1ERXHO3noqBqr6Q7oJG0YvvkNNqScpGhDMt@VnDSYFAaeTPkqY4JJIYR1KrNnm2EovW3BsPqBJ14iOMLsBHBG1heTSaBcVzO8O2TW0FpK9o015toDXNOvRmaSeEVYI1ey5/b1AOCcWx4u1PSP//TP@c0OFy64fyHcw8wG@P5I@Drg/idejCyD75/5viz4/pj7vk9jk80eZxfZC3Pmg7u3gS@fSTN1QpngXaRDdfFbG1v6ze4hc8iki23ZV4aBZkIJgzynGUAvrQ9McUNtjOA8h3ETjvFEz98AiwBfAX@geoMaDeWn2pdRPNS8lk5jwXGemaJNwOqQ23PpjPPHAd7tAUpYupAvrMhpKGTyxkNIBw27uOuUI4zF1kAmhm40q/Kh2cKzBExyWoquVgplzhvpJeX7nPTBL@gSwIb4ROGcQRo8fuCngLiqSBZdUuJyDJPiQBaRIyjT2iZnNdAGo@QAkBgGG95JLVA3TUEq4GNDHbqkMY28CVAT73BCu5PKb3jxECUBEceNN1BMd8fxPlLcdh/ooKlgM0hnCHaMYGvSPGY9/55duBfGpbiJhAHj/WoO6xrg/sdzrifhnIVHL2fvxYhO32qBtWHPjg0T9xtvQ2lZNJvO5tJyIRbgUEmggvJiV/8MKKFzg7BoqdqVaTm1zfrui4PD45n7HQgyMg0WYZHqevwimUqcX/qOiF/uSaJubKePX21se6QMlmq8Go8Q4yX56WLOy226pA/kfsY38M7mTREzGcmZr0VM61/JbdqxMot9HJsOAG7yjYMzuUZjd/fnl@vVCyM8k/3neXfehFPLyFzgunDoxpvIdDGxiLvetuQTvEvPSXnHU7LS@EYn/1AN94@DH76hwb@Zb3xNg7cBOkQHKP3zk6HUA1ujoe6pNM@K7ijgBfPKC7LGK6qMRR1n2ArN7KgIloaJusxeIihOCPlEOuA2JO8KOIdDOiScuZWJ7krxaebDnXgYseuPL04QNwb0oHS61gzdisOt3vkq/2BryrF0zY3GQoaAmD5pNQvpPHr/gA@mVM6HzD8y5KDOOEyRtS1K1/vcXob49Q3Mu2UhThc1HA6AboemxcZWtC3Vcx2BTsW2BpBFCydkLwZ9gOvQ40jF0UIFLSsJiYGeEa8o53g1gaBEqt/OR4exVE8dtrUujDjRWAJE03eyPL7iQcE7CkCvas6rAZqlrJ4CdcCmya3jDQnD2HqJvOMKcosmu50fbFyGABkmbcbWuOUicmp4t/Fgw6@xSMKnTDOWiKQYn0mJi3ZoVZgMUSm22cM9dGT66HQ0UtmCB6f5YN7R7H4KawXDDGeh57iDNsg133TbRoAyyrmS0oy2Ooziwea1S6QThEduz24iMWmGxenKD3HBQ3v67g9PFiquEErjezOm5F2p5Mu5SdFQKqV6TggPn8GkBHI8du09cIKKEO30FYtFB3R5isNSjLzRi6iRcFw7xpJVHK5vmcHicbJpwIMiYM6CoB1yaXRKPYp3jUXTFWgkDHWMNj4@aRY7l1OpS3BTJjG2hPbMTdCm0BIYC8EcFZKsEVrQL@BvDUvEb4ZMiRsilyjbEN1fAFBzo0lOdXskX4AWVGtWfTI@LB4QMJyqpdKaaI1JaV9iwBfrcwQioJ0jxb05AtBXHB8CqqGMBqhNW21rIC@fvVQNQwUCAc/08SJMZQBMZscS3h2tifEdapRDmBdxR5xHgoJO3q1Wj9zpJqhrS@kymcbK96DWfLhAvaYjNJtR@r9Np9Llu@iSXhmlQdeMVaNLvYoczy3H40vGcnTJQG3ryRO0qN0vgTLXSMEEdQhAySU9VgZ@BuWvsmSUl5T16FK7kl2mFOCFKfIdJPjBSafulpT79NITUJYSEGJzoRNdcujak0wqJd9D@bCHLKUTwDN3eH8H3byK2S9p8TiWIbXUwAL8kL44jtOweXGcJuNdWcwF0t2@6G5TqpjfEjM3xnICiuA1f8DK44AltpU1PODxzWq5eXEPqH8845e4@ZbRngHVCU6@pMmYrxcsQk6jzBVCJsrvnQECDqNARPQmlFgMhMlvfhOWC4xJTwu5qBl/ms@U45G8DNN0mF@Hn4Eenl6WbOnuYit5w9Rk5Lyj5FMfLw@vDw/fxi6irMQi4c0DSV6RvmelLPu6zyrLPvBhv80nHF5Oh8LpZfnJajr94cMHmHHA57yaqoL44J/YeTJyeR5dZay6urqcKBSXE88ijUDBYtFsNnbM0uxC0zTLabfha/bomuRomH@ePqW8YPoP/4yHifyFw/MgiAgNfyuckg@zi1VFWY6vZJ8ZZShaCT85JoMTf4vwlVk@z@r4@dv//W//7G//hP7@jL7/XmHX7BN8rjsM/8n9qR1wK@hudj7htTAwtaiQXLAikXwucvx9hP1n@ywyufp09T/9ycHHsBuuZtNnNjzd8MdwoRjmTnCAL@f5bsLV8DqCFe7Do3SlUgHn6n/6XyF99QXgwZjROvxU8x6uwihcTVYoyedwtQAOOZuFfP/vn/0sFK4Ow5/CsiyHR/TXCGdk/BSfyE8YA0daWi1KpvnMK@8w8PHC0rKcvRi3Z6C5sWn94B7kA@3KzPAkKLl9rmKCG8jxLXB4EXBh8dmHLcZUGGrxs7b2bIbge1P@o1QSPinRDYboSQ69KoSLlUSDZ@/zajjgmKqw/8tE3X3/N8KFwt5tlslzpXM5QfWLsFxcOXg2/OoPGxfaI2J4TDs/czYd5lHd9zCv07NvgQuFf6hUjlz8e9XEv8Nj/PupYo49hc8i/NE/fHwv/i5SiAgmkNnP4m/RXUPh8/D55eXrHv3Z@Ldj4F/zI/7tfcK/1y7@nbTw7@g1/p28x7/ZyoTC6@vr4Xj8CFRDwbNf8zmFbyrVED6PdxHd7/TDVg4KB89CLJy8jCfv789T3w/j5bL4B6Wp7Pvww11QrMv7ZHL9@2o8fk7FO6@Kcq4nL6tQVl5k@vl@HRDH18/X11ONarWavPy@er4@mUike/Ysjv30GSSsXp6fh8J32BYV/FnGn5aDv1lJSpMXBwsYnUvgYuSkhwhgdJE9@kPhD@sfovGn8acZPXOTka/l61fmwfj/4GAIEdowc2XamV6mJ7dBIrKMepoZZUbDTN88kNvgVOEv0wenlukMM92MkTFkeTScQPXwf//AdF8dmIDNhJTuMOMi4kwHnt2Dg1eArwN5X8GflslkhlDIYeYG/jM6Cmq6I4ue3zdiF6FzJn1QYfRPyZFUJpIqRCLaZb5gfby4u88WPkqJSOPiPHJZDqedi4s0145YdqVMN6Td3zca9f2tRiONfLS@FH8WTz6DT6UaXxePp@Fq@enFWhLbj/NfqhFOrz@9qOaS6C7EoZGyELaejn/jZ4wSntXFixBM@M7O8Ht2e3PLXeQg18XZmR@LP2kMIhcFwQdA03PTTzgYaJq/p//2wX9Z/69OWfT8MsZY9O5@PUqfGP7FYnf3d/fitxqLRoUnug5/GAB@THJ3X0UnAd2B6zwau4zd3/Mw@I3G1jnCKuaxXqXEY0DosGGe60WkDBpeZSkqFtUuLoaZTKzchBDfvK58pvWZWJl2riw1cU0NZgPycoxA8ivl8opwrxbL5aJwy4VCubzsQ2XAI5wApDpKq4yMXg7HsAic@6MZtKnQLZSRaFvt4HXkTy0LJnZyKfP5sx/UaLQ1u9HA8NznzxfQkSK4b6VSykNIpvj5M/TBSAwmffumWDEtwRROTmfRKYMzv75eWKlWCyvgLhRjsbJ0vnTHCxHtxktyjN0vpS9VR@JlhMlWJMx3u0Tl4mqMQu8jS2mpzMLr7GkV2NeBD7u7DxMl2Uo@Fm2O1BhbKUSL8ZL4qyzG2Hq6uszE3/l5Lr6yvLr87PJyrCJghy/fKRX5vnKnrOF0/77cEtc54iY95cmTXAmqWMyUL0KNxlbtpNbAe/ElCaWpxRiGkuwI4TqhZUfOyTiTL12eY7kvLyKRtfIz3kbFPAtHygIuGQEpxIolql4YZoBaB7fnDlFIi@@avJzNLabzw@8K9QxozJ@X8XN@fl7MFuPLIKWWS6XLy0sK/bxIac77w84l3RhUSZ7LhfxlElWRq2FnGQorr@bCyyGLdgWtZlgbF1ZtNHYtQmBPcVgT18AdVde9KzRvTVtv32ptFbAf7tU26yeJ7DqgzG7XNhPZ49ONsIze/NhP0Tn0H9VrWwenkOBwr147rj/ffVM/PYRwBwY8IBZ8@oeKOlAb6u1gcIv@hkqfTc1Rrq4Uy2pY8Bl2fvzVz3/81X/341/88Y9/8fMf/@LPfv3LP/s5fP8Kvn/Mn3/8b0t5/P31L//Z//zjv/4LCPz38P138P0/fv3Lf/Ez/iX/38D3/wyE/Y34BuD4F0gJ2P7o17/8k7/89S//yb@E778S3385/f3xT/83/v9/iT90/sWPf/o3@CM8P//jH//wT378wz/48Q9/8eMf/kNA/vd//Sv8/5O//vt/9yv8/1/@zd//9f/w93/0P5Hjz7nj//lX/5b//t0f/Pzv/vCf/90f/PKB358/@vvLrwj/5e8h5OvL@TV4vqZe3xryy59Unt@GGuNciMH@7B//@C/@EXDun3Lffw8@@PejfuF7/Jg4TdOS8XHgLxj7nAZFKPPssw8KKP9HDIVg9nkSG4VmvNBf//Kf/yUGT8D@oyCGjDwLu4TAfm6/ANh/7RcsCPuLH3/1sx//8h/@@Ks///FXf4QCLblSStQSSfkLMx0AzH8FHAIWvgYOAOV1XNteZIuhLDgW19EAEZLjHz4ASRfBBQr1ciifA19IrpJbRjckhPnJMp8hx3HeD99haKUEPjQJxGEIifOoOERtxFmlUomHhhWII1DwYpohqxZxLotzgArgxUQ8TaJRBP2SDTcIC6SsxI9YY7ky5AnjGFAlDAwLhEFHkpyV4sXKFmRYGW4xxIXI46EP8PxQqRYrwyqi@4GKADjiG5AlQFWwdMPqD@CvEE6ADw23foCiFCvxeLUIIRWqKuWWaFCecp4qR3WPM6o3hjOGFrGnzxj7TpKLEp@LASmZgMbf@Bj6KVkknkL8RXxZVIf@PSd9lzE9tNOQ6MPDePxTDKb0AgDwJpO4Dwq@ySSW5hlEDzmqOGULjzjHAJSLC9ONH0CjbDwUp/aNkwfyhzJ83We9GvAgOqzO0tISuNarUk46AKWe2ddrjqvYuExAGs0akwolCYNxW4m6dEhq//LWMvzK8F9fpK2hnBzLoaUIDuUR5uWRjOfMFTNMpfeqRnVZppLHCS4UHodzVZPWekBHXGGxUJTuhI7R3FG1QIMJvXK6G@YQ9MGEJCXkQombTMXU8p25tlb5QV5ZDcGT/AO8jlpcjAzNgK8oSmHvQoJW75Lr1NPACepGIVStivUqJoeqx/UTSHBywORsJsVAibxbWc2u5Ffy2VyhkF/NyiuF0kohX8yBhCpk8tmsXFpZKRVLq/dQoGfQzxNry838evUfzHz@m38w7zM/FD@h6ls2TLHDw9fJ@1B1mEyms1TkipxfLY8qUBAKClVJk@L68uguCUonNk/ogrZG3eEuHCha6C6JrLoAHxZaCLEFCIIPYEZrPRNLyLsHZbGWhpf98/U0Sc4DM8RCF8AMHFvICn5C2HBPQNo8kbkzXxg7M@gMneABln3IANrBYHu4adE12YnJN8dtqK0HIDZ7/MVWm7YJuudPh9lQjGsetaXh5Xgt14/aUfD2G6evub0HIE6tPh5XUe3fG4Z6vwkFRIMiB9iAH1s3zXkAq@z08IFavvIPuuHSHJ10A/Cj3ec7J4HnSb22uRMqsI2D/a2pR14A5dleffvE967yWC9p3kfxrr63N@0VD5w/LLL8aiIBgg9@8JmgDz1TS997IHLq4RFRTWUSMgj4xki9Sybvmypegn7Mr3kfdnTTkSORrtqHEQz6qAxsjDtju6YOU6WlzGYGVw/Sn3Gq01Cz@RFbAoFXgjkfW89XC2EpLxUrhUwWBhW6fb5jlMMFmP2dly4rQ5ZjxfNLK@yslEu50CvcylWS@ZEEzQntwNykjzdv44ltN2SrbZin3Bp02qKJb7kZWOzBQHhgEDptrdsDoXdr@gAwZQw1FYXB91s/gEMNftzHA1yeB4XNxOiz4KFb3@Ljm3KYb9MRouAM9wPTWSBv4ZgGFmctdIIimF5@xPDcWRPfF0AHwGBs5wdi6XZ/FQRyKRTCxTKtwzKhFJnAsqVivljKZYuJYqm4kocpYz4hZxPyanG1BBySkYtyoZgvyYniSim3AuIYYvOl1VAYRJbWSadhtJEliZ6a0cL7OdfxolMz1auGwtyEAEM8vi4urPgBgyKTcsWLDIOEUgj3xS4PKxK@kDGDrzuUpZCksBYLb29vZra3JWkDPWjv28xIUhs9@WIms7ohSSrFbMKQkYVEPfTVC6i1SpKGns3a9jZiuEJPtog4JOmax3CP7nlWAcxATy5Haq8kffTRZQC5yUtUpFQu92QyG5uSNODFw7OJAFfjvhUqbB09GIGJtnnMJsRJ0nMvUQbIIB1xOJHVjlffWk2SdrmnVkMUL6jyeV6pl@ip0QcS2eADzpekLji6NkzlJakJTuR/SWqBqzVSIKwPLjxxaLiKJI14PbAmkjQkaKV1LYE2J8IhHyjPzo7Sc9tql39GNn@2IGoXorThoL7dfP682e027VGt/vyIol682FGuRgO72W2KhM0GfExMBVHX/dH0R8WoRkPR50e9hChjKqoxaqhUwobyEUomPl3MqN94gVEvIGre6pBACJ8@ADfxs9GH54bS5FHeh6LoOWw2pTKyLHadTpQYV0nQo8lidygOo8pTUM9XpDWUp2YHlKpBMZbMPx0UpcKqtLYMT@mplAPnMJqJZBiTIheSFAPJ@FRazUtrkadPk5En8lMmrZakNWl1VYqV71FxiMbuOtFhYljJQEA6vY79GHsePEFPEUrGiTp0Uzsq7sxoJZNnE5/19TOAw9OheLBuf9BnG@yWRAdus/d2GjcqGyAnMmUDT1@r6F0ahoehaltxFZhubNwN1tYE7H25WzlHBJ/xZz0pnVXPpEsWzDe/moFSnRqt7Or6@vnnS9C1KnJ5FIZRJFssD8N0kmJ1pRwF1T5WcdSPXOP6rKONbLFRyXDda8kZ9M8ziwU5cZdsJO91xXGX5NXs2vlg6TwpXy4uZj5316X3VekSs0eVjP6ChjwQaGUI80jGRWC4o32AeLaW5G@RkIuFWAo3fDfMToNuimcfApJunNAqwxirq6BoyKVsWYCErIpodIlF8RUwfOdJNBJZzUYisUgZoBYhWLQmcYvX3BJIWmjuUhbUwbKtugNQPjLle6@cfhG4KlqQQ@H7UBsvCF0phcJ3ofu7@/WqN7a/ZKOREk963ieMdeMwK0nTQgMuUSySK5mqPmO1Sq17VCsL0NomzR2Aoy74gaZkevFblzPi69Xv@fOiist7kE@Ik4eW/NLr8Wq6Wq1ehCRJCkueNTpazMOMA6flP4Tpfje2edcZGHTGe@0VEkxZ49rJ@WXsh31NvyvmklXaSROF/nAfjq@ncZ0sVU0TtVoHtIocChumcKI904XuEQWlOy/h9EZl1nHp@9Xvi9@/Oj04PdhmzzJrxbUiJwUt6z9LJOSIHAHSPoNRTzuqh8LWZzMv/2C8KIfXrEhuJZKbUKsuKuI8bxQ5IXqO1vvz3OXlOUxdLmPgq1SyT@V8Mb6yJq/GwlU8V5hdDVfJAd0umQtfhjmClVUWAw9ZjrNyuJoW4fKqHAs7Se6DNPmwEwoXX334DNNO8YpKLUuudFqUaul@/R7@q/fnMDO7pwnaPf3jTxp@7jkA/CO47@GP8ScAF4QZx1/@kFzn/@v0s3nAyywVgOLhD5UqNOz3je8b4VC4FKnG0xF83bLYfyCmPKgQLRv0pzrL@Pf9OGAZdLhl3wfe9WWWr8qMqcvpdPoi9joL@kypVCgWwqHfzH7SyzA7W16osQi/KoXrUfTece/gSmTiXVc4qV5eSG4dH2y@hLkrKFKqge/8Y5sH@ymMwtfSjU8etXRVsfWReC/dCKFQ/zrZPMQ3V59uHVKaMzpzRqE0dxa5LO2218RrIRI3TE7lWDaTyaczK2k5z@TiWmZ1LVtgCggdB8@YC9cSJmVUrU3TGnGtN7oZo8QLNYTBuD0NpiyOusaeH@5RCjp@vrywVX91wA72996lvFAefrKze8yOD7ZPzmpHdajHq/oxk2rHbPdYYme7JzsHpyestv@OQfRRbf9kt36MCNIhlFe4isEJ5quEbN0ZOWl3ZKkO6YUTwY7ZulbdyXDFtpQ03vw3GWzguwBUvEJ7MnxgwLyvHVQ5j2sLMBMctPBtva1rpd22Q3jYTWuxBRyuF5ZVG3eESr2Ms8ryg7efMnZ@kbVW9iOrrJXZN3Lrq0zPiD@mr/RzR2xxcfHCkHxpH6yGr/EGg3CbNISNy7T7vr4QLaywZdBzsyuxccz@weFCxvMtnB2dLMh@3NHWQtb37G4v5HxPHXwrvm/7bGsh7/s2ai8XCuNk@5sLq75vq765UPR9wKQLpTHO/a0FORPyiHVjau0Fet9RdHt3r86WAShWnohFawY6poKBENGB4fCbB5DkbHn5tmfi69ph9jOagm6rX4L2wCegFlArOUe6XibYsmnBT1/tAzAko53LUXqvld1tJQRWvAMDRpDQXWgBK7SAFQL4BTzzinBsscKyMQbRCx2@Shvl1/kkmHTq0Mm27xy2jrpBFZghQZdq0AlHSKGK15OFFu4FymiHLD4d2rZJoDKUVLKlWAyPRe2f7u3xzCzIwrSjEkEy8khzcJoWYIMqwi9WHUJ54/BmobZAWi0IDQJfoRa6n2jN0HRrIimgngsLLUAwSd0bRU8wVLYSuGSIeNHDt1sDMESDOwMufh4sGm1hXbuq26ICxZCY9YNtXkNcdKywyVaOMcyUKEXRfCP358/M8124k1570mtEOG6BnBeL4@MlrSBsDMMWvIN4BEGHjinlAnJMPA6poToUF6jXAhAdvvyMslfKKmSUibAnT6gc6@ArRSgLTBenHFkSQRCBIBiRD5H5RVuk4sYW0su4vM/fP4xExHGEX8TXHPn3K4BknS7oVKv6vdBvzgVDddzylEAWUZ02tjW4c9kG@FE8AicnWBO6SYJ5kXIBI3FekWBqgnUgeEqmNjQDOFe1xzLRYwXojNT6@1u8hfhlIhTOA6jGIPfWqMFAWDzB7kuMvrDQtFXluuxBgTwkKOBbZJooEoLDPZ7uaIuSLfP@gmyJqb8m5e72msdHPDWwg@A0IivOWjiviOpSYHUMNINfIMP@WwH0nCU5snhcQPhcJsDqk3DJJIe79/jyC5WoT9di8ZtrgWL5wVrUv7Iav10tYFgbswjUAkR8FPDGAZp@JlszOw8FjIWEgmrz01DAADrmJejjEwi@Ij0MueP0yW9PD4P02nRXhn4LLcilAk8y6W1NetuTXuy@EKIwmBJkV9hn1kSXXAAXngNmRXC0uaycTNiZ9JLZocJUL03Hl8A8B@A5FJUcDBlwVhijBEk5eGm40scXV1RYbbuxu18/mYxFfCmnIQrew3c3Ux6xSTBRIIx3ouiJ@SWKdpAIXN@MHvI8EkTPxvHJUb32KgHli7H1cQ@Y1gHgR/SEiRrcezlAqKG2YDxuJ1j0uMaWY@wJlizBhGUAPV@dhW46KqB6MMf2wMpSVhkO4vsne1IYe2RoTlZSlEVj7PPFBQypmVUm963PuX7OWM212Si3isoux@PrIELKewJmn3dNrmwgJLCngjdZzM3sKpNhK3aOuWoPNO5hxp7FT/W6x7GNhkXvtKJl0qTMKdPrv1G2iLsdYFycVG0e1yJpbEQ@wFDsxhCGwznZtuKknyN7UqynYPGytNVvLcuXNNrJsiR5WdYp09ky/EaY92C6FJo6kUpXZJiWayl4aFNEHlhoNznEIDsU4vaUwE1JURNfF@DG1uiGC5QpjQZe/NZoRB1V7@A7hAd2C4Z8VJcdAYYfjE3xSOpI6JiMFORB/Wkyoq3hIUu8sQ9GnSmE9CrjCt3LFqUcQyG/ZI6rWlSqQDHQJobv0gxmiK@DD/qhWfHwU6DEsTWhFW8r2B88ZOcTl9twHAOnl5gTDOJ5NtRn0zlxPtvMicM7zOYl8Q7lzom7GvTnlQAEwwMx4ljdnBjDPJiXgN8NM464PA8Q8DxI4MvLaGx@00O/mmzxwOU@RP8Te6CKm2p2DwIsCMql4MBAW4e3VGDaloaXME8j8g/2QsroMBY4Y@yzVWzMSYrT0rRp9B4mgYgOydE9w2y4hm9jH34nZ4uxRABhACNePtdX9IdwsgBSKOEcJGH@2mzmWTodHzWy4DTecfoUHpE32jC9GycwrUfgMXYMi43vAS/g7UZ@jM/Mc7rcGN3aLONQONrisfnliXugHoL2KiHHggT9bbNPfmv2yUD@2Cd/UtYVdj5Zjst4wL8GAeM6eh38J2XklXoyt9g31TjINap6/QD74n0dgWz4Of3JbH00QgL5POVVhdBjwFcKCcQVRPQN8oWaT5winpd6PP4sV1hS9tNwiTfuDWRVDxQ@hDcMNBp4NWejQXeyNRpoWWo0JJ4DDbw44AUHXdHZeFwKtNSGSbFRKalICSmZrB1v7u4mNUNK8HtsK5LjmrbawKuVpEQbJkoViQRWA2F6qm5VJLGRSnEYpZYezqMWyAMq@OVMCIjnQq86D965@eXsWsEqmV9RJXMqs/E9gF@R2xHlhkeeH8vJ5hdqeRlt0p1PeImWrWooaPgNveJFtHg5wsSZfDTpiyLwfB2y9Dl4EwIvEj0aGCbaGq8UoNf9VhhZ@yTvjhBp5koP0dvR1IMIxpzKuU86pPd6MLovqq0KPYvMQylpfFegKFhK1DTA756Cxq9YGA9ok/eGiPImPNukg2bMqaKOBYtpYeXPJbxWBBrg0LTg179aBNz@5SLgxutFMMgTdeDGu0UwRUc4xDUj4KKLRuAJ7C2N7zXsK0OtP0DDTfDwutDkxsXCIR9rQqM@RU5KP05RhEjpeEFsVOCNxaU1Caru0KUm0xebIPy8u01il6FZIUs38WIxA6rDPKRzb0uJJX4HjRRQxFA0O6I0kDYhMYkrIZRWXruEyWeAdzwRg@rzVJjJrZ6ICGqS8NOPx6vA3SiViekFUgQmD7ww4wTcyhR8fxYp97E1XwUZt1gQiituc8qN@yAfLHgQg6eoxUKPzKT@fzNPCjbJf6FTpf/vJ0UzU5/f81TmkSnMN89WfofTgv@q0P9Xhf4nKPS/M23@AZV8GuVsj59S17@ohn@7@kUybwTDht29QdNb9qfoYb8jRWD1m/QAr9Tn8mO6wJfHZw9NNjis/8RROvSb9Em7cLZt1mq1k75sHz2vdWu92tE78G9k9uJnVysbW7cbzzfata2t7ovu5r76ulhb2bNevi2@e9759FEF7X3n4MX7T7rV6oXeHlm3Z@rhbU4tOrXB4OPuzsjd2Tjtbx7n363eZup6vrOhftzSna1XJ29fnjzPH8dvP744fPGpn@k7h52MUurndl4V3myOzoxQ/kY7bW/vaQf943b9NNvf29Lebcc3M3vHpddyZq9@@z63eRvPZ9K71suD50enV836e/1od@9de/OjqRQ@Xt9au@l2qbN5dfQmdJB7Le98PDjo1rOl5zvp262O1c5kd3Q7f/X26HDj9N1O76VS72/nT0tvr0aHhd7r1zfufry7clYYvHJW4kbt9evsS@P5zU39KNRUzBM7p56Zr2Xr9vbQLPVX1Zf7O93@a1s20gf5N/Hj/sntVn1D/7g6zJ2@O3t9u3L8bvDq9Yv3Bxnt@LhZVwpWs509vjpZCbX6ud34zWn9tKg8b5@97t/s7uTfbaVf9dT9WvtQv37e3XlvHh/u7dZyzsCQ9zZv9HfPe1evrrc2d3Xz8Fo3aivpvH7SfndwEDp9oTW31J23zovaVe9dOr9xvfIu3raen1x96l2/2Dg@PShmh4ejjLnpHDV3OsOto0K2mG7pH48@dcxX8unreOHm6kVWe1f75IZyn0b50p7@Tu0bL@Kt7vvhRz0dP5Xlzfe7n969O965sZs14/Tjm@2jK/tV2zhwDjJHL16@aurXRffKem8cH8utzHP1@lU8o4SGpzsOtJF6ouRXT/p7r63hlvnxaPe9U/gUvzm7zqlb10dvah@PMs1bw3pr2HtafzPTPlBqb0y3Phg@b5VuTq939L2PB8670Ku6nM9vmx1no/NmpfQ2/TzeuX7@dkM@Hmb2jaPOSsHef/P6TNPqvbenn45a@e03VrHvGt3Xn0779Xh9b9j7pBYzTf343bUROs0fHx1mb42XWt/d3jl6VXAPMntvDts7I7n2WpVvjdXNUX5raBdyZ1tv7XfXO4aVfqd9HBxm1Jt4@53lrrzWmp3WG63Vfxk6ftE73T98c7ubL9jP@4a2cVjM7O/tbO532ysvR7uvBvW95lX7@e5b9a11UrjO1jfOCltvj3PuyfVLt9S66ecOi/ETve92T@OhF4PeYPXwzP74Zvh@pdZvqrkj/Z05WpX7my@s7PBNrX7wqXt9aJn78nZ2lD7dM6/1zKeT2087TqE2iheHp27fdE/kYV5@HcrdfrLcF9aL18cHGy8O3r9QVjTtTLk6ftPO5E6Laa1n53YLhedyfbvT/9gvqfKnrVc5JdfvxZ2963R7s3365uxav@q/7F@1QsWS09rYfT9QzHozK2febXTqeXVvY@9EVk@7L49XtvYzh2/bh6cfhyftzbeD0zcHWqZ@9aK01115e/Sm9HL1/YlzopyZb1/a@6FhMWc6cqGUv80dl4oHPfs4d3ZVct@/vCps6GdN@cVutq9ua/bb4qh4bX3q3XZvj9VMs/t866Ny1KmDJD09zCj5wfX@8DiUe3PSv1m1NuLvrlsv3xqyXjzTVtMnH69K173ey9ut1spZ7dNHJf/8Si0db6eb@nb@efxo8/XhVXfr7FNxpZ3Z2HujvB3We@670OsdbeuqdHZ9MBzJr7ePR/1axtDzN8dn@ZsTc@P4bOe42HvVtDvNnaseyIb@6PTqdnCzo672hrfFl72rN0pm721x03BWDjOhF@puv3108vJtLd7JqiX35uDdvnVWPBvmXxXNs5J5UNRe1jrPh68POvXMqqWdnQxP6730xqbWL4JMOdRP7c2D1zvvz15YmVDWKGx82jTzqx/jN8N3hbP0YXxv8K51ku2f2fbOW83efntz@PblcW03vtscPT@8Vg7e1fPH@5ubzov4tlZQRzu5W6e2mdM7Zsjpbwz3h7ZVyr2/3uvCSGC2S@3nJ7kzw6nVOre7xeN6rfbcae6@UIbD551VGCPwUz97Y1ZCv@H3loX4lWX8ofBrEUJ9p9s0hyAv@fGtEB2wCdEBmxA/UkPboflO49@kl0MnwZMy9PZHbuAZNEFZY20TlYcU2/XvAcXXACRY34TkGrpapkVPROvaWnPgos8xdfglexUeEKN3ValDSzc1fMMK3vaOc1Jb5afQQH1JhQ4M1h/hfNNV@/z8joYvSRHXdtIF8fxdNHRtYGih1WLeG71SdCml/36vD6BAWEY3SbeQdlky2eroStcBh94m14fQsX9LNuagawoaPzALea@hyJm82JqK6ioV7gTf7bL/nOkmv37em3EooEyM6EoINFLRtRAqviDU0W5UfUTvE1DbqRDf8flVuyCDYbiNezKMrk6c2hsK6oZqT20AtXhCb6U1vfwMr@x4tpwWS6yoDDUUu6m5@I7JBn8NQYPn6O15syb3HtJxTLFAyxUj1Gzo0lHu7CtD9E2lQorRdnI8ZOCK7FE1RBXV2224vGwRStp3xbgngHnZehi31u/@rlBP4G5r6gReE2g1AFrRgvTMmv13Dm1y9IHKIb5YX3@7e9IQL53gWww5pR7fcRmgctnzWWVeg0D5Rclnt2XiDgMoPpod@Z29UNUbk/OyRPsecXsktDbOsMe7Lekdylh0xGbRbpTzlUu@gzBDW/c8gvtpnnBOeBIo1ZMxQRfEhgqfB74yHd@gyUFm64uIO7aqEgDt5vSOgUxt9vsd894DLdPUFeMaXWW@VRbmC3Yr0Fh0nX6gHmjK8usi9k/SHAHrDUn9bbDjgkq23ywEIDbEes18amB3pv32mIa3sJ812scwD3/WpetmKzqOXva23PC6xbycOPxUVgdoSezgzlrTHvGM0DwTLZcBBPfpkExQDW@3aqDWlTE1EB1t6gmUAvi27AXh2W91XM4Ee7y0PKtFYgfaATS/qHwzEEKd@8W65Fk9LAuB3rFgZSaSjonjbSECZ3qZuaYFROgIjoNhjHiE706doQrf6eVzEeN0Os9cwj97GvSs8Y272KFUNHuiCIlhN8YZ@lTh/EIjaNXvOpjVmPWooXAHNzahRrzINJjhYzjT4vGJdgogP9eQbjKLE7Wjc2JBDPk1EqQXtCcY2hMHrcG34rIO38HFaR2aItE6ZPT5s99hwOtz46F3wBdYwn@jLTI450zelwVBy57f64S@m2LGRPGl6v3sXnrk7i5MwM1bSxuqehQEZgNfpmExCBJbliyLOwjC374EwdjYVHYhrxYXo5DqnODSxUv2hEXl9fXoajJKQd8VYzG/M4rk2UDyQGIQ0tUqi2aXozkv8QomBpS5SQQr8xFkOYKV5ajsIcgKBHIeMHAVg5B8x4qcaycRFwOIfbyXkzD4So45uS9n4/Ll@noR93gGAqcSZ@cXfTkXz0JijnohPhnD0fKIQPjlZI0AeS4bGEcCKFbiOUDBs45PRoxznYrwMw3muXI5d3D6nSkv3jkNb/Ch5PhmQNU@L2J9kVP5pnSLgdtybRGIb2ey6B1N4zDO0svI5qAjUJeE3HoqHppK8Hd0iUEL6FeeGhUDhyMIAsUAEcHDoyXY1WNjXfPbBzsE7pCBj9c5weQEK8I0BCQKSIwiJAYRQjTQuo1W3/LhYCguxviObz6AUSb7uOKM5wegnVDt93IiMcbJhyvcgE@8I4nGEE7fKCRo7O1u4ONN/Qh3zO7uP4cmXMB6JNj416vmIsfoV3FTMfh7GzRXgyKAbOMTGlFX3lST@WOgl7/A5iEX8NPYeUKqHUIwnlhoh8QXmtvQTIGNk9LjI9UlOtJrhHyAYqwM8wx2qzJFR3KM@OtPi/xtQ3TojVITqcDhJxQFRAohzU6OavvH2wdHr4hyh43a3uFODTHDBLOl2G1G78PADmIYqs4HVZ@eIRx@QULzOilN7@UN9OpgguUvVuPEA8AGxTQodLpEWF/O9DPwPHheApIoPjQoFY22as3BjXtXfTBRGWcOQt6KvNRiKBRlmjcS0oA3OxJ6crSKko5oaaqOEXGBsen9IIrB5Unaw7cBs0x6uRr1XNSjusQvNn@bVC5Lr5hFPnIGFq4Oq20pSH6l1VIdulFjTH1AqeodykRIlgChIGR@7cfyg59N8cdegYPesEeDbsbXe8dq7qSyCNojp91P0nEDChLH4ulId55aSWqRyJm/8XZCddQmVcaHMuO5XfHcriA3LnDZ1bRCpl2eX00oYvPIo3nkueK6saeZcfXE30pOLdeBTu/08A4YsoVwqUMNhs2E@4VsczQh6554TfbE68XjnjhfuXtcKROEndTIxIAzHj/FhLndBrJFZ2wbdHKFZl8DG9ufewz1Fj00UvKDTt4Ug@CJUxqgTntwnvjEM1QPcgZiAmlIp2XORXaXNKj4@KICIUt65YkFdA06hSmsApoB0mJ8OE3UlVRJ0xETxUAgilUxCtttr5MT5Hgws9vTB7oQCEP5gcPxqQR@jI9nVEQnvZ2vQqiRQ8Y6K0VwXTWZhAQxbtcgnQbELdaBiqe586tRnK2GqJynk2n8BAyKOuGWuShA0M8w74FQL/Py3HoH6uEdhsPEsUDFMmVxgsI70Xt6yHJyLhc4/ntwts8KhfHpYLyRiq1kM@Mjx3g3FSuUQj/JTja2J3B@xI4jGhTZCnkGp@6gC6q6Dp2YP9oaDv1YNj4tHvLHqOwrV8t8BusIcSyGBof18b3fTRXfb43rtS6Th3IqtABC8STw5nRv8AbA7kCxFcNV@RlLFORiZRczpISow6q2w9@qTu8VB4mPr72GYcFWuQEYQtpmizZJIg5KBy096NNupAQqDDeqjdcAaK446L9AMkewAxcNVc4EXqAnHKoeb3ASCpFAPRqNLJyMNCwj9bjpRbiypK6c7GWolCd7Mg1p3jtIsQBEXsEqRGPuDi0IAs8MMzQfXxYvYvK6pA88Fv3zTIOzgwyfnHrzcIGGjzGzM3/tco4xhrirFRyDhmITE6GiOl3GvDNwJAG8I1Atzw7BgegxvKThiXDx2ShSEN9KrnFbOCMZQVoEjVI0pNjIdbhLR1w6RtEL/luYiZ8r0PtiYmfASByY849HCghk@RiHEGcjpyGwf3KIYRAHlIJ31OX0eP/BEHH4591QfBOHeLNwdMfEvAAR8HktqV28/PxM2vxaiD5KmfIjadMlpahYoC/PB@NVFmBYuwAYFIrkkVcpD@z0cHzuzQOk0pNB6rHCT@T2tYUX2c0ATVDiK4vuE@Je2OrmIYXEffNG5YtUYluNUDMD7cOVJGhEwQjEs9TvhalC0MCTCrx0zUAKrjN7aTxJQjHi0O@syBFQvmM56x0H9gS6b@Ycn@udV1HOyV5VvWpSC9KbkHXNoqFxsq6iWwTrmpRnK7saqKx3yniisiKRV8/Z@x0McHR085bfv4ADiiROLkvftRPsuzYuhoiQ4BjlUWOe/Js86xzokN9Xxj3Sr59fVjo063t4XxVrhyjag/yO6RBvxuvk@CpcGgJkBDeNsre5nqdaWBDqDCg9E@myMWF29tnZQ9HpgLymrfp4t@he1sM05hjCUmE/cDw0BH1S7QlgD@wzyXksQMyHxdeBB2EDXCQk80Qn9bgDI@JxMZ5VJqzB4wPUDzJiEIuQnYEjyo@mJ5kyW4oRxvFhcj4OL4kY7sf9vxwsyOjBgiA5aI1IjHX@mhG/EuH@t10ZHetultDcQO@ysvDzUShiQn/LZzw9IGqN9QV/dsDnA0HdQCjanjKIhi1Q4GFuzI9GJxjk/iD8@IaRj3yBD4/mQUq6ASSYjK6aCAokXsJsYFpkBSYxs8Wk1iGKWrxNJstNDUmGEB87r8YT6xyRpbNJXAbkzrg8U6sJdIwOOZM1rswv/yBVFi@Gpnlq8PYPbPhlrDwuWY7nWRYeDvZ2OxAKrW/pKj@5I@81age7/tVWTLw7XHVMDHJSpt1N32rXWpoDho7FtVVJdYD9HC@p4jGN@ikMZXjhlJtixyrfrIB6L6plH2g6qQ5iHzAR3oBlAHCnAxqvga@yb6ruLe4fEAicVLCwEK04oIebBhuZZnNcekWczOEFSFDZHSh8FwgzaNKLzluK66gjNY0J000dfvoK3gSchil5GmuYPjDUPUh9DF1CTV0pN0poK1AwOjk9lStdNxdKou2IYlx8dTLtHkEbgkuvD2@a0Db@/lQxSaB7FE1DHzEDrwDoKvgOb0Zvc4WskPNuoZq041Ys6tCWB5XmESuZUoGEvSNGOEqH43cqBXH5WIi/9nMNz3c4JrKLrdLeVEo@sadlak8G75iTmyj4PH8yrIWXc315n4a/xSOdDqQ1ja/Z9zFvjwfd/wVkf2jnRzqN5lFLV0ZMulXoDma2ubKaKazhXEvrGsSG2FvwEp2Axq4OLXx5Jm4MwHHcS6urN6rOctiMbzRnAIDH7gCqFApbttLtKx5gNLfGMJvAHV00v5440T@OMk19MqSD5ybYeEaNJ9MYk8fY6ASXGFWQmCJYjAtqDKQW/DzFLc@mabE1cLTV5qBLgwGey/JS4OkoJdHEBEqsGm3GnsJzDZ5QdLqYFPoxdv6Kf38V7icyNXYO3fySeQsUUjlEtYCuX@GlL3vpceRAsMCKDgzYfFUDRoRl1hCTUW4lAGgcw/jlqCirhaFANTyQtrl7gFYbypBvLvZisIqWuNTxwT0lyyywpwREAt43hYxJV2Cl055lJFLD16B6no0IjyWrUZS7xyYiPuot@@Tw9i90@O6TdboTjNGNnUTOWNnbVS@X2b0HiHtAUMPBnSXJiLdzADVMG9dmxjtSgPSSNwt7DG2gALkvQFLDIZvhuBSoBt/gfcmtXUIFmY6WL701LAivZMoeNfhbk/32Hy9mPeGtuUAVX6R3MIsXOnWiUosvxNAqiVhgmigrDl6CR4g7OC4xxEc5P1DAJDcIayIZTRO@QZUXlNtcQVigzpmkISXBhqyL1nc@fUqwkfDixeGEaVjJJEYVuRxC0YdnFVRj0L/DyUiCJxlYCQS@ZypI@3IIf8WMzuaZ@70bRgkS6yjIQyQoMOjcC0fTxl0mweT7MuXcojcscREPesQs78/di3VhIL61c5iK0P8lHybWvmtLCZ4fLhmQQ/Yc2cvEODdORL/Uw5F5HR0mRiA6GJ5HqopZB7qFcZ68o0AU3VEi1mmEgEE7bEPBdccG0i7q3UDGGsMKTJAaowra8Pj9X6jw8m5BF8gg/BoDwGQSAWGGyjxll@KJzCD6hvE4xsOkbjJ@YK3hLNtLPxOPrUf4efog/vvxJXlEh8Yw0RjFvH0pkKIxWiYS@NtT7meqS8X7Leo7U96p@s7Qw6/vA/Tw6ztLz59UX99i/JYqAkMMPXCOg1P2pzCjxreue4HcTvGUYWBmPEJtvZtOPbDwTTBTqelC/9nUpmWZDt7NPL8EPM85haD4QDjk@ZTnsQZumCCnuflILmag6@F16U6Id3HbRH0xSm589R0fv0Cf1LltW4zRFICYS2TR973JKT9kEBNDSTDIE4l@/TArLlO5OgFq2zXtL66wQFZlv@BUUT4HY5TYr32McW8AR6DqtH0RSuMlQULF2LwkA9Q7MN10Egybn0RQXcjHyVRIdTY3ldeImFrsrvQ0IRI70i6fJY21bimw1tQg6QzsGtAn/Hmsb@8dxj0G541Blt5I3BulYSq22yFr2ybfiM0OhXUKjz2BCu/2bHPQ7TG8KAp1QITlW8o7Jmr3qF2CVo@vUxzgXTVr3ra46Lj6vv04zU4tBpN8Oj@PPffVIdtExb85QlsytwVEA8OE2GG1sODpTgtjk/YCSXof@JIb@rjFYZw9tVmgAFvID1CEV2iJg@yPiJ3mZOwNYknZ10AkxXXVvuWiZq3xKmD1x8ksXIYZJ0QNwLvji5SVBR90fmE5GwdKS6ULFncPWGVeaTNzC0nHUKcL2VTR1Jd5pHDcijhtu4HiYO5Ymi3199B@fq589Rrm/V9gTcjU48oEwakwycXN0aDs4NG8Pr7GE2/W4JwKM3BAuW/aODccJeZivkV7HPUu5RbmXjRVRrh4ShSnB/PZG9xoNDc1rbj1FGgqOjqAiKAEpFrxtTNcL8O3bmHqVzQd9RPzCbBDqhzeO8uLYbZwldlLPEsJ22ypattBlVVBXqFyRvF4g@iu3iphW1O6OEOEmboner3ikD2aZos9rcVPZWweYlFs9eNAs/lkG0uTgrakfT/ACps9tXVNsPiumTH2pGYkgWyGmzQ7zPk4UGw0OZg2i0eckJDxfKQ5EjtxpvUoIaDKE8DEeZVZJSQAjOonXgU5xVaevQ5NNZ7Mo806@LqIiCNeBSFsRvTq1oDtB60mKQbyyjfIwPCsixO6mkN4AtPvBOsMdJTFppXCOJSEk5UN@lCxbC5W@CWGE9UMeCaAuGCdjA1gFNtQbB9DlIZxMRJzSfNl8NIMNGb1AHCSQ/tzrAB9faIBKSfoNrG8Q4eCxvYLiCb7eRT5zfFgOrjXwlbFFALTZGIJymQWLQ3Fs1gN00gGMXOwWcQAh2Cxr22/yn@m9mOoABkoe0DA4PF3tDC2FDRWUtHF7BN6OtUSGVlUBeRAf6C7iqGaA0cf/b4ZIbRAL1MUujMEjcj7Tngn1XGchvHZWRpfBsB20we03Q33JuBEHYR3dm8NY6QTIWqw4fqmGGeZLo7BOAnv5U@4TBQ9wbg9EYeDo7cnYCoGr0xASw9uE3DpjFeCbxsA0UnHxQw3Rem8DXZKyx2QEO2ZuLkC95QO0B6EezxsPCJGTYICG@uCyE1LtXlmwG0jc8C88Rn4dXzVJwjI8V2bGmQqhj7Cj7IZq4V8zwcSwIO4A6hwy2FXDaQB8QsFB3CyHUG5veGtqQobBQ5ufHULX5WIOVC28ETcGj8DN87wJ@fGV@HQ5otZIu6pdBm8VgA6W8BKxvfZRxfF/D7mTfSn9j@RyuzZujxYzlBibz@uJNCuilmznDeB1cq00SKqVXCnxjqesIB@CaDn2uViBdda@K4Nsp1hK94Cg6iK3epBlaC9NGQY1yY6tbU2kQ3mcGj29q8ydxigr2CuXIE2Bv0mXknTIXr5xzRp3QON5AASHaOOUc7jo5caSTgtDvx8gVs9yX7cjvl9i2dF8xKc/ACgb0fCEVSUieyXgjDoH@9s8qnTiQovmkKySBb0n4tAvKZE3Ec/E5W99G6u96d82fI0RvkRjLGx8WzqSBgavNzAFqdb077mK0dodiPJ7yoa2b1xLZBvWMZEnkUPF/mdcRxfyfCMc@PXmlB/xoGlp7hfNvJ63OSCUNT5gR5@cGpMYL6GVx5vWvZ3I2c4b4EIa3ELVFpE4c4onpavXHLB7jOPt@bKbYj8bFAmeHRL0LoS7Aq8rYUpk59rs/WO0K4meENACo5AaK/kaH4XJkkvjyShISheeD7HocLHKx5YWRx3SgZD7nH6z8vpkU/wimpUM15v5PxRqXDuGOfhbxJuBbbqLnvHG/h@sgny01tNK/4LHH4a3UhicHNqmQ3F/i46aTXkO7wWpubfjNf4HFXShYXRt1CHaOFvEx/b5CXiZtENaN7hbwbMct6YmuV5grHDu/6coypikyd/3QEM7wxfpiCOb4A3aAx33Ji/XC86qOOmHJd4JzDSJ7n0Af6e1@8U3THFVWY0sPJEDq0XfttKjNcDefai3zUHHSwKrvRDmvEBldnTKYsdX@TQ1ly@4M8pReC073CAOHj/jwV2C3oX6vNTKwBFR1bECr9IeO7ZxBG92EbdETYyXgO23BDZijp4VxhhJWjBO3CdDc2qnttqFx5HGpao7URQX/JXvlOhLW5MPDzY3T@pHzWO6m/qR8d1Skkb@f0DxQMrTZYy5xYv9zYE3ogzcSFO6MzWYBzHEYfes4Qz8OP/t70nbW4jue6z8CtaQ@1iQNwQdREcLiWR8jKRRIWivHZBWCyOATkSLmMGIrAUtuLcqaRS5dixY8d2KoedVPI1SdlxVfIh39f/wb/A/8B5R3dPz2CGpHbX60pqtbUSpvv16@t193vd7@iOg0A8AHHXBXH8ZRtKtmduJvXNvfYwPe@Z7043ufwRM/NkfE@axr6HJkIzVFWC/p2yAM7Pw7afY@KHM5AcUqHW6wA9GXBcqAzumbCZcw7un7iSOmOK@UoQ0rIBj5RxPzhFDlBKE9E3ZjhpBj1YzW5J6tgqaLxyCP0laIcIyABAPmrdLkoUQtpcqzDwLvCcyEZiWzkULMje9yviCVe7S9WKXe4X8pDtwXh0nJHeE4wWEOcGh1YBA1RvqiEmoyCoAvUW0FMgjjT3iDtURvmgXC1Vyp@dS4PwEfs35K3gE5jkf0I771U7/cT4SUlm@yoGgMHjLGM2dJGwSYkWdMnRmqIGdbGKarKiT2ZOnm5NLtFf/w1bkKcYkMvWbXw@RuOfrT33pc2sP7WPhc/fDCeRgCNWOYp8E1VMl5@dwc7/FauRNzMXuciK4gvTiWTTCRlQ7U2MJ7LrWdI@Rs5j/4Av7PGqSV//@Eq7W4YzivFkateKKNrqCDZRpfkwHo3URL6cEn1Egz6iVv5rU4dP72uCLUDY3WS14zfotWEcEelo5Y004XWgngtU3E1t/WWk/apeU20fVdqnC@Q9w4s0XHOyuVEVadptXr8WETVwtnRhHV8if6lhrs1blFN54zJOKaPLs0PdmXHJmPo7XwomlNZB3gIZI4vDa0VDzElqNW0SJVylHlGIl3JUTuFaro5fTG09HMHwspSciJmX@LKt9jqODQaiorMBbQ9y8TmKoAwvY9NQRqdGzUVaZXKhrdiE6Bf4/y/WVpoE2cDjCyOr36CR1RdWI19YjXxhNXKe1cja1fLMn5Y73qgMrNlAFE@B@8@swYLaPRDvvXv3SBy9uycePLv/2@KrB8/Ee3cfQ8qBePLs3sP9@wL@33v8dE9QAf3ny@4UVe4FTP2u23Xpdr5WqWwIwrwSoHxDPG0PxbvjrvsKiGfLbw93TvijNHKDbS6198qdLsb8HDRBZZZAWk3QXRG/NakbJ7S47gAlD/EdUfnyxDaSN0@fb5bI9oLCoWsDbn7bIx6E9LjoWUkbbQD8GFIBTZufZEl3Gp/WiWnplYQcOP3njUcQmMJHT8Xdx7sY6XN3/2j/4PFT8eDgED6ffBXd7IjdfXQbc@8ZZhHgo4Pd/Qf79@9SAjegUhJ4t0YG6@c1oYTgNCrdl/0ZhgcboFQovyJevdcymdFYWUX4Ijsbhe57ekBS@O7Ozk7r5KLdvnb38EtfRq7G/ZqwLAxyaThUlxYI1ypoNAK1ySjadXamjqxlscob0nAhrmF2PUN3QPS7IBTyHL0Te66w7uM1Ij5IU9xsZtgUaqjoKuBGVMoRrCMoAkM2W9gilNtQG90eqNrwYrWvPrDojnTMinLkmvLS6hNSDM64P@pyGF2VAHTPWt1UbTBlALwQkgkMgHcwmBC0X7r7eEkibkiIWYCCPyTc5IQXw8mDU@Qa0cBVJtzjQCC3ZZt43mhKMcBR2xvxPEbMmnh3oBgpVMQneHSSMxioK1dSiQP@X76x4assQFqwC/ZhZSuhInx2A2qAvf2k3Q98YTs5vA0GEcQdeaypdTxog7hH98JTNFh6hWoEVO1tB/9sK0f1iuGkQJxKhOksRLQdutyuPPjdy5aDkvdWakS9Peo0KkzJ@E8XNuDeSgM@CRpAVDT3C3QrNAmIsSU0474kZdsfA0WCyCc@ikY1GvdmXTdSQMo69gvvww9zcpALYRFDxYdapzXsMNQDPoScog8qcnMBQgxpSp7gaxTPoR3tQfg2PERliCk28AM1uLI2U3hQNUpNHFkp8vMptXbaZAx3Ya1E8awbrLevifYZRc/fPpvl0TNJB8VkLc356M8ZlRjQs9MU3bz0BSoWLQJqCQd3yIR7x0fCLzfev@1s7957Xvzog0KzXD7mbaHd48cLVkrkZxYSyWF5aN1J0gZUK00izfizDpZW@oy8W@IqV8iAcTnxgPneadV1Hl@rrqaPKF5WNJ0SX792uFSR7E2IhDCSTLi7FURDVVmgMk2RkwjCvRMai551VUqBcOr9egfj2uMs1GFERriPkHqNGVaN9GsMb9f4oAc7S0byaTzdGn9OxSKXFEV/bHM@yu/b95z8dq6soGgx6eG01RZdUJirOdmrJU4vnVcr6HbPRwf79@XR3T63dXw8vBG23XOxvVHbivl0XHwsGbguj/ajc9Dy4faJ0ELfC@mI@ZBcxaYpXRNn4dqaovkLavxgZe5o7QEaPHsxoqpGatQ2Gw3QQ5zNl@LQNCqQM9GEDNHTo929w0Nh7eEt2yaUhX2vPeqSfSlug4j7qvJ0xHbItNmVNNOkwwRp5kmlLNm8NFrteYs5cfBStgrJgxTkeOjNQkftBclkLq0j@GQhFgINr3lDVCMXbd2Z2oP8hkS8bKAmlAgnzehgJrGba3z4sJN92mTCcSswb@y/9CaamXHn0lkXXVVPFyYixQjjcdA@xpfv5Pl7j/njTVUPM1ju12bUYVTC76K/fPEUKp7gS3EpOoPnTIuaUtJZISpdU2NHZnlRDvvTE5SOxb6UvLCxrUvmWDaN@eNrRiQ74k938J1/ITO7Q3nfqbZ4StkyJzQXHnp29AgCJhPEYLFjUgUUby7lEUajoc9JRzPk5lq7Rq1pqFZSNDOJu54O9BZw8DduxreHeFWw255bVfGzqYpPiUhNRtyt1RpUJmC@eePG9Ytwx3uhihc/LW4@Q@L7ZzCcvGobKP2FT6pCQLn7jwsqPySAc4bOASmwZ6sFEysIrE7CmRLpOx1GZvugLadTtMWDxhw8OyrgfVG81pyYx9qWjJ1PJBM7gaz0wVjCuqO8alZGf3l@dfcoqNsF9V198/p4sSEQ3ocvf8VhMg/HE9wqgRGfttgrKojkmz5qxQVYgoMPak@/RgzMHRXHssHx5nb4hRttpLnGnWD8EvX6VeRMGdvMwmeo0rA9OXuNF1yv6cqU89AmQJb1CmLnBeuocGTNnd6YlAj6OpTlDrcymgbb/KuWGXxzE9UHKY8BjAdMRw9g9u2sALlnE28VVKjJbJ7TgD/RSUVOAloNUPbQ6eucjnYJ3mSw0OllTu@5GHhOp25JLKdtHfEyuy0h4xEys5YEprtar79o0bDr7Hc4G9gYnfSWbAzIloOxTr3KqahTpZIasuwsTGpyEkhSOmlNQuHB5AUmLfmu@7JFkyyjzQHCbEGMvEGzJPWn3rGl7JiTJhwBTySUd0e9DE0KxTzVqNSRsIOuZSUJNXa8ZokUKOUGhDJZOLG8kHa8sIAJDOlG6EsmKi5GDcC/ZSNkU03ixZobOy@Qwqeu3525Ym@OMr6KjaiokhyDrIm9x7vi4IE4PHiyF0WNLW4hj0KllMIehWKWDaPuqCVbgAkfz4KTFieqz3juqcu5CgV/a6DReGoA8Wc8V1VAKJq4LMXZ695r0YDDe6Inxe7lmnLSVY91H0rd8WwUnL2ev6bpnQOnVwISeEcsS3hJ8M7KsMiVKDlsRQ70FodhIZGvbCm3CmEtlEK1zKVvjrG0uI6t@dxSYsvo/ROmDlYmbdJhQE7YJnEnGCPLsynjW8JwdE/CgJv0lu0I2443DA@lUmklOS9u6cCNrhlxN1rZJSvJp1VyJ6yEKUzjKfkYRzSsLSd6Y/Hae60qCw8VPPpvx6UdPdrou1lOo3HE0LKLwFSaRja/Shh97mWiv1YWnJxBEY03Kl83eEFgkPdwN3eYxiNgRN8rYHpzUGC8gFbgaBVEAHmZrABS@VWMreRWhksvoUhyi8P1uNqclFpCdAlFkmsJGx2dinCtx2ajOwbujAOS4I8WCILG@Zo4c0A2KxWnLVYRLyhJkcSZFtdp8z@5hDrUNs0QQI9N9bPaZNMbkTWLnQsfHRGzBbLzxoDgHkTuVPBYM9Or8XTzSBLbRvE4hNGoGDDgjJ1UF88FexKJJJ2ipRYvKzLaktHAkdeSRyNsOU0DlEgoBbQYBeVVE8ICKIIQF4cniwHKKzEKmk8GNYif4E2ssbYaq1GD5pNBjfWxgrWYhDUKmo@DruxrtFFGx14ztOv2@ZOXS@FjTXRGVe7c7c4CPmmU0wpYQwEsD5PRktA979gL3hEho0W/StAeJNqN29IjtkoDAf/GLc36UAHFaptNkNWGCHG3MHgpL6Fivo4y2beQMdfMYwSeQ1zj@7gB2iAIcxoEe2CSDVFMhhRo1CmmWDFzaLjUPBB1MkYSllg7g88lcr@NtTMWdzjyu1WwckuLm1WP7KLQJ5Us5aOtLTUWpWDc8kTin7psPOEYT0QURylMOudPBMcs0Kl4xVEYjLt82VlAXHUlrDUgHQVwetiJ4cDXlNW@qIKApnlxO/BBZRUHNiEvzuuUiUMJVas41i@NQwlsqziKl28HyVNJfXnr0jhYEEzCUb40DqTA1TG11s4AwZL/tpJILTIeaBYlU9uFTpQ0NM525KsT74sSVQXaCxKGCPw89pXUDsmYm7Q@MMSgS40HCh2r42F7vJK24SimnbvCF8xVLJlbWS8s3FIq38AaK68urvlBDw6CUn@g13fC4o@J6LFLEomQ7j1QiCl1T6YgIuFslqT0oRgQwgntb7VQNavVopuhJ4cHXzq8@6j1@O4jFKLWeI/C6xvUliF1nUqphvHs@balRTpFjkBVC@xGhvZhI4/aJ9Hs0SlCkWOx1NqZAbe0mIHCmhy6LyqN3FPxALIoaP0KToQs6bsZmB6b2qA3dav4ysqFkOYJpnol5bVtaAnBMJ3IlhCMkZwxhC0u/3zEGirPR88DBuyIBttk@k2zvc/RcMkoKETx1fPgy@60g7okRe20lGcRVfBRdiPnVKhyIW/QQwzGBP6qXBb3lFNcab/WHnTR5e2sT45vh96gPez02qXJySTT9x3pnsbO9n10cplBZar9o73Dp60nGKdr7z5ZTuCfOuUd7T/aO3h2hDlPIeu6TN47PDw4bJGC@uGzJ0foMTSWZJmAEksIJhMiQI8P3r370IDhb0s2kg1CfJA34R/pyqcgvElrTn8vyMyjwKoQLQrCQ2YqWJTSCiLwhu54poK3of8JdcAX0PIEH2WgLhXVmBzS2Hj9KfNCX6dLA4raMZ1NAgIlDXg7NhK5aAmGGfrHWIB8EfnAt5M2fYlvlDEPDfnGEztWFg1ksFhG2nf1fVoduEyeLkZdW6GTjjwLZ@4IIPG1KTsL@sXb2WUOvUpOSGkoXjhbhpOjTM5Rs8kl5QhKrfSMEcTIvHatZ5TBO0CRRQlNQmiZQgX4BbEu8nkvd5YxA0TJLNhVOX7UmTBs6KMwMn7NFWOO2K0p6/lC/Ugg@pe0wNE0wp9PzEcpIjD5PkXGHA20PNdjRv@qzvINs61nx6b3qdCuu4TaI/ehwXcDmx29kM@@kO7kc5dsQAsz4jMezQP08m1MdpgqZBr3gzoMVDBdCLYg9AM9XNDzJv49l65du6hAYwPB5UxYy@JcdkeJRkJ@wAAk5lnb1mboxobNErTiMENsmRDVJIj3TYhaEsQrE@J6EsTH32IQr2/n82rytkXtxg3WZo7MZ0Lxf9PFi0UFu6VUocPCgM8srk5jRrLHOCR03kFzUPPMBuRmy26e27Io6o//HXCbuGSpIlXCDT@n2edg/vnvWZt8Q3eJUfpr7qGxQSFzIp@82IQZ7wvvSxJXTZK2pHFsPzkHm2WpWUwu@92QIt5PIZqPfxqBSSabb6t5F3r81AvXlbBsNbRqiCP4j1UEzpsgaHF5tb7I2ygb8GJ2bVNjUT0IETDIdROkFgdJqvL1uVVWTHzVxCqrJkjlMlV@/DNZpzy/EiB@qCFor5WDmQj6X5GFRqr5UCgJ1GdItKl5Er76poIfR9tgFksCfxJipyLN89v986/H2x2WTIT//UTipAImfalpTxz4f7gsjuupOD5gFMVi6rhlGSKfT4X4@EdhO3h448vsvEXy8z@8uHQlvfTvhqXDY35bHdzMNShk8S1QqwdFM6loQ2Pj@YMB0CkJrTGOUb3mjCWHZ7E0GIt2oKqzpcVZNLumsheJ2dd1dgz5khksxSWhfz1ijLY4wiCxRuFvsvJlhktlbjsm15bjDpncLjPr0sAcxkbzONIUx2B6tmMCx3pEyFhFLXNzktlbZogLricKP3572j4ZtTFAqz8elWQEEG9c3huOX3h4UE3L6Oai9MJPk4Y@DWtNCEiOc1B8vYsKFdBU6VSEdb9ZbkfAdrc7G84G@IbmSLkKHSOVy@gyjgTB0WzoS5x44t6beQPogYOcWsgigpg3gVbSKQys9KWqj1WdVO1qleUy642XyA0dJVHbulNvElBlzqosgC6fiEGFKrwtA1ax8GigfkaI2BWtI/vz0Bu5tgGPUVy9gpFAfhHyDpeqE2XEx8TAUUANkMezYQTDmZxx0o1xOKfko8WPXSnUcORcpBsxdTFCiLaO8HxRkz7oyLUMIpEWRNMollphI8ejRIieAHkOoxAbhVoFK5pgFrkoIs/QWrO83Se3RWTUSjgIm4amWQCOMEQvx3W7Ar2DDN0ux/rl337r76zcWbms0iimjjdqg8xAEUlCrPh5NH6ivg30KJ9IW8UY7r8PcTPqntv1hm2MUBMYqIG4UjDDBCLmMyA0dFo1HsB@Mz62DV8wqkIkrHL57u6uOHr38OA9tIbiSwSiglhxJIJNYeV52KlkJF8qBiOIpIRVmEeyYgRSjViF0r1CMN1jcq/Ttw0NLBitb/wxjRbd5Y9R053XZQwhZlvs1AfvCVG31kSrJ0JRMM7DN/6IMY8nrD2bjHg8sSRhws@JC8SvriLtlX4xRHJ9v/j@n1F10qIEeD68VxmaVacx/ZTbkBeyRLPFajO1V5FqaBBSEV84RN/8MSHzOUi32ggzV8xdUSNJ7vYP/0oQDnx8gNkzSooInvyFiL7NiPTrAY1cKr7ihfi@w/h6Hr0CmIg6i2gXH8E5WZqi0ZBtJJcvGL5ffF@2GOC9AN9MzqljPdLcTOJk/Ks5s1RWTkfa/Br4U2f4ByZSaeaahpEPqkQ83/pZuEzNbrLrZKbvK8bqjDUtscPf@s8k6iMdc1g96AGc0ZpTlbhWUtr8F3@p8c8zV@YXEMwv//Z7Pwr7OE/t2Ty1P98LV9N8tRfztLZfiW1JX8Ejw8rPU6fip9FqIit37hifaQh@kjbu8@hgz9OWPJC@XvTzC5Z9GpJvKyR6wc8vXPJpuL6jcCUu9ni3Upb7PHWZK@wpCz2Gfz2lmbAY/8VcjPPzZj51zaeTxd8QcmT40Hh0ZVrKZcnhVIi13RJV@hc98@K/2/HWmLsfXrWFjIsDHBWgQ6kpQnsINd8yV/5ZPKb8kvmaMLUqnS2oHhm1VGUtIJq0B35CVY7zmdVVw6EDcS@hlu1PVklmWS6PXDa6n016KHXQ@92QJI8pPf9h8IDknfHrNJfAbYO4wtY25J6gQU1u0guOv0I@iI58DilRAz1A90DcoH@3dHeLVU4heeNKHMtgzCzRFbpOR1EoVRCRkkS@2kwUKlhOTVwI/6R3IJauOixd4WDJPpIf2TDnws37mz/SO5IepXEUewxl/mKc/yingVSM6K2cPHZIni4dtRP50oJUNFUdAalH9z@bu0WsunRe0gBLw/zdP9EHneujLmsP@oMmr@TxH4Nj4sCknoDG/sk/CYGdWw@3jNSa/1RNvM87VFrleJJdop6Uan78BxaSdvIgcXb9YiFLYkyVscT@Y/Hs6d6hOHh29OTZEV7ImI4RtQyeLuix2M37Mgmw0UuCFVm2DmJ@jcVZI4/Jyyt4@VqOuv/n38PuM9q8Y1UsY5jOLfeDSLmqKnfOGNFUXHqE5PislOdLC2gd1y176zi35QiBAL0/CnC9@i78kGB8McEOn@XZxuTPJtOm1C0rZjyXmPrPslvGZUz6ZQIedTgBTlXg/DmVLyjj86EMurJa4Oudk/Sax/ihF8rlJ4F@3hQUudlMvvA9PT0t9TE81WzqlVwf3RP56BiuPDkGZmE0pktNdJsNhOd1QbZF54Wz7svwV7HbHr1q@6gg884cVaKdO28v@N9M2h3x5HjIoTg@6T2xEHTbW1gUugVAVuh0Xxb6p726zGDDYK1wwonI/UzVx9BXv7xJX0OMA7xn11mdwcvueEDcrtUZwEFmhVVzDxXkQn3K74nHhjHqEnkhvZ8KYpptVqQQ@GhAOfATuCplXezNG4tmpPhcF49os/gcEfNcpKwQjPmsx0FhA@acPw8rVdU25tJZvDYhw9cHVApRkIhmoWAiFuGYM2el@G18ocI0hFxE0tDyp@tQaTXe/AXz6CjCAJqYwIC7drnx/vPG8@bId0/Xm/nycQEdHSF0R5o10piSzx7@jaM/eDWYjP1I0sj1A1Zwqaik7omkBqYVVnyRYxXTuIFmaYUbLxw01A50KBO36LuB7UkzVdLGOaHnbathhWPMDWvIxuBIe0rJQKbhw5Nham8iahqIMF13SUXiS9KFst6boj8tBVuEMUcHMKMFmhFioIboUpExTMUy2ip8LeMEGHb2gRvrisqHqWjEsoxuLuX8m82/@sbN78O6SG49ESxvijGlsbkLG64rlwt7xNx2jHmFFpTX2wN0@Wftjcg9jVIczNXXy8o0hevBLsigs8bkd6XjCX5JHUktFKxrgbKvWDi8LHldqCHVmibhKzzlK0KQ5XkD4QgiCcVcWWxuFgNJlzcOehZLKnZqNHJOjZxzEYaepzSyKYthIE/TbUMTnba14TwCfFXW6CWxUPjtVxifil0RrZd1neGeQ1SgLAxhQpHOus3E2htGo41NK4YACXEFQc/tt2eDYDMT3/CqRf2l9ygeSrVH8ZckA94rgMBoC66zUpmtiUy@WOBVukduL@FXI2NVC5VClf6r8P9WQSWq/6uriZUoZDWaWCnE/vu1JDZxZJPFomplAzfkzK/WxGQRnIxHtcya0Ge2oDMb/RHyC@oLn9@H/ZE3mbgBhTkSx@4IH7cx8Ks3xhsLdP6FcXXg90uX/ItsKuSCn2JbL/wWImpJRKXJQljXdiwY9@FkPA3EhwOvo35jjPKbG@rLX/joRsp3XeKBfGCC5DM36vseTRf7wcEI7yXK6DE5GPPvzmDcKQ9BlHen5MrRhzUPEN64NJ2NyuRuyh318FmczBDaL6FpJ1AddK3XArAWdsvOIeX5LrqntJ7P@32LnLe4g95TFxk3vD0SOpLKfo/4jrZ/YuG2tiYeAxO2ye5WlA8T7aWLRtwVWfkYVxxwPGfSGMgakb5Q4x1jWZJmhoVK0fK9nlz/WSV6gIZSVo7YMjtHJ@I4COGVKqcswIohkRLYRwzSx4wxnhVhjzBEqIuWJbIReSFkArUj/JSVhglUkTyfvQKwh9grZUXr2jCtzDNWN9G9J96VOdWc3ik8tJOq3t7E2BzUExxQnCb5NFy9jTnkoNIXGHGOfdOY/cg7siUAyBNCgRCBx56iR4bOC1Iixcs6ODyQ/koqD68nOugSbUAxXvD@auQeU5QUcdrxOBRMz/MJAEuWjz/0JnKIChFS7cyOgdWmtUCRVTzfn7k3bt3eoAZRXCMF2ht3I6C1MmBG17JlatxJMBzoXtwJTsTAfeUO2P8bN5tiv/CiJDqz5faJ1803c0Q6MJSRnsIo2HcKnLa79@Dh3aO93YIoVm8gOBuoaljbGFzOzlM@GXBIMsIivHxLnZsbTOS2X8julLM52fQdc9jzZoMVAtizpijHTeysQ8XkzRwjBpGph3tVQcdb1LHdUFcblxs2ZTbFqAWWGly18tfWLCRprGsNSTCyOUKZXHhowBdsPCtAqXsFjIDc3VoohGEoIaJca@tqsajX1Cb9KsLGWixus525dR/k8JciezgbRXbbLK2dtsjCJofe8nhru5qlfaFk1cWJk33Lz9aRO9ec0yt7ljtTIf5GfWyFzQN3NL63UPNnz5TWCgxIrlFt5nIyIfs//w1i3zI0CxjYQe4M@esPHeUStsSb@h570LSzfBsMxT4sBe48uE@ba@AEdV2gM@4tShSStHcfzt6e/aFZx8TOnZF2c9dxrufOoMrpBO1QJrAZukeAMVfHtH4kLRQ5nj8foVvcdZS/vvLo4bsw5YfoX8oPGu8316@VC9ksHPGkgeRgpA@xe/DoCd4kTHMlulF4MB0P5bhM27qSEj7so@Uwtb5gYdfKuAph5zx2A9l7/97iqH38uD0EibkNQxC9wGmbWj8Y5h51@c0xcqzo5Fq5s2OHoE6mbr/OnNDSd17Zx7l6AP@cmFXcgCqcWo2wB1DIQQcCsVH3RnBav3v06KGT3WoLxOokrIpsvqOJAwiFCMbGJBJoI6SD4XSRqgK22ySCgT/5rLUd7ctWub2drS@Xqe15OG732ONXNiTgnj0rSIqbOqtTWp@GVLCYuA4m8NH2pb0jqwBlUfbFRIpxtKBNi50RO6oOJjfcKegIXDxFGMfZePttSsMiM99xapVKDtVDloCNfEAAWl5Y0/py2nZ6th7I9sQr0dW5O@e6iDmplWrl9sg/BXa0XL1ZuXO98s54iu8GPdfvvu3DFuK0MaSsFyzeRkN@Uic7Hg/6b/e9AT5YXd1Yv33g3fudr9x5enPX7nZ@C3hI64U/xgf86cRsgJpJdlZevn7rzp3K9V6nevtOv9Kptd0qfLu9fr9203VvXb9ZnLRfjktDUgy0mLQRZf8clLX@jcpG@6Z7p7JRu9Wr3q7dutXptd3exs1av3qz3y0aTFWIMgP7n9oWcWuPb5BvpfNemZWtV5bO/S8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ _ye{--}besizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]=x 3 8[]p#s4;93
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

Run the code snippet for a TIO link.
**Warning**: TIO link hangs Firefox 54, works fine in Chrome 66.

The code is `ₔ₁₉₃` in emoji section.

Answer (score 7):

## 203. [V (FMota)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V_(FMota)), 9766 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqRIUWQ3dWupWy2pdWl1t8SPXSSLZEnFquqqokS2Wh/OjBezPh4/2OPZwdiz9jkz3sXOg4EdLPbBhmexgOfVGPg3fPO0GCxw/sHZiMisYvEidfd3ztn1AqZEVl4iIzMjIyMjIy/VVJzer38dxg87MvVRVzdd5qqOy9q2dqPaKbYxYs8Uzclnc6EQQtXs7qCvGq6zFgozmTHNaGlt8DPXvFYN7ZNqQ3iWMcs2u7bSZ25PcZnqtBRLdZg5cK2By8zO/GQ5xrb75pWWxJR9zegCmKvalq26FL/C2JmhK/1mW5mKyU9laNkQ77AtVf/c/@yyltnvK0bbAcgCY69M21ERvqU6jonJVxkbbqutKaRFAFVszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqFi6OmRK03FtpeVqpoE0ybCTg7OTo6kUsszenO7sTIdm2cukabCdQet6OirHzmxH0ZVp/CusNnDNPXc6PM9qXdVQWDZVSmWnIwtsw1ZmkqwyW1XaHU1XU9AgLMl6qm6pNsMQ1jFttgdF0ouZYqZRG6dMtTBtcRw5jbbE9FzOnapPNgOEN@2eakAJM9ORsh85FZH1I9oaZaDYIxZ1eqYNfGSzgaO22a1pt4G5DH0US0B6NvzEmoqjFlYQQc5HcG2YtwYwkWtC0zZHrsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZvWaDq0xF5p@/PYOZfhHWHTbENrTMXJ7EiBIMpmkvC57GQvaEHrQmdmVw4UrK0yx9AsS3V5JPCKalM0pGa6ZlzzDn5km@1BCzuf21Mhb@ywyA9OqAWpqswSYiKFDhYmDuJgUIITs68Gy@swQ4UGciy1pXW0FmcsdeiqhgNFdlJMg0rcarrO2qoOCcbYWwnmmNi846CmrvRSrVQIGRNzYf1rnWmsZVmMR0EtoEg7mSJTkXrsE8TrPYcNrT5ztD5Euy2z01FV9km1epA81DZDDD4ta6pavm9JBRhD9UijWiAQkDQmUhro5FHo1laAtLYjaOBqfSCs5kYcpiqOhgIVkjiq0SaqWr6oNZkywfLsRoMOD1Uf2ITbUW3qcoQXuqetAkrFb@bora25LvUaVmNHqmKzU1tVY5NidyJLyMzEHFysSIoadX09sn24E4HG5SlSigWNaedOX78IKSxVYUuNMnwrklQObR9ssbulS3RzKQsMYNlRJcYqPzAnfXmpwncoN9Nd@z4EWENAFZ2lTctNK0kLCph0oYBpBZ3oSt5kU5YeyJitT7VFgOU4VBtaA4QPe5OgmrUGto0jyZioyjVUWjeNLtATKmsPDKSHwQoZaIKWCQNBgqk3QDWQvNRGIBeQwqc9DRrNwSYJdCw@HhJBYUQENhYU9fJ1TH1AcJDScZGXgSqQFDHuddgb1lE0HZNAPKLipbZVZ6C7mGZgtLHlYbxT2ynmFYM6rA18fAPZKYCUAoD1@4F@SYUCYGgIk6qKUT/@0z9rd7uAp9ZqgWwT7PqGtc0WjdwKFRaGQ4YMCwJVp2IBXAJz58khgxtF19okIBRjJLKgQlCut@ZAbzMTMrRvNeilPeUGejZ0rparcibng32C9ZVrLk00zrlQ8b7ShIalDChvqnaSPduEVmqpoTDxTLI/cDtFlrS2WcRJfx99uhZ9unipQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9K60Nbq5ankwSwBzS2iwe6qRlsxKQQihzrFTboP0jwFg8ObpHAF4kyngSTH6FQgGAkzHXbDA8Kk7CBfmsggIIdSjq6qVjSTkmMoJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICq9p9XgkHIkHq04YoKYTFcXOeqqZKLZ0q4eDFhDFcCwYCWzk3RaM1CgZHc0FjTPBmsTXNIqAZCGZeKtGbBWHdJ@PqEvyLofpkygoBYZxF5rsyWo70JFBCEBfdp0Zaaybt5AhlQmHGRAdBmaqdKFpIDGvSI1XhOdEIZNV4ooGYGuqrJhsatAJsLuBTBc8H6gbgOeyHAaw8U4SkD19ZQRYWnxYHXcYpnWgL/VBPIA21FJR5oDwUfmAgpkMqP85oGOjtp1JZvP5yT4208VcO11Lvgch/Sn9aE/Cygc7Ewoa1lFvma4Y3YHSVbkmxpRWS7VcIaigJo4Lomh6vKHApBg8U04vtPRsOm8aRDzVYpwHCnneemIoVFC6CEU/CeqMyhQxVQHN0QaxpI@mcweAm6nMpQ8IMlGAD9IDRfA0AGAydai2Bi5INWDg257W6gHPYukMLhf5IDSdPQQFcwfJnuz4WWNh5OqTbCiV9oOwGA@iSGKLzuKBwRVRVScCqPGDAY9jVpz@HMSmX0QYCAKhqbSSAt77As6@aZhzkAIhfbQIMhnD2wE0sRNUKGHg8tQu6qy@luk3EbQZTgTayH8917WcNRgnNLc3aKaAU9Kn9mjPPTSQWdKuPdJck7ubutkEsexA/0x7OaRbg6Y2nKoQhflteOWEbkAB6zisAiP3xwFwXTTScUBgUvgmAgeiJBLchIL/SgBIQCkgVLTjkCjeAaFyMjJaUSlFXSkFnU5KMAk7rgTTHQlT@XTZNPsohdg5KQao6cG0TzNwriBkPol8Ze5Q58t@0usikdSVqRnRu8ji4mJkLVIFyb64@BRc6@h6iq44uJ6SK0kuhEuhi1IkyIWxF5QCw@qR@wsP8zBWx2Yb4qj0SbOiysXaWq6eUC5k8cziMwaiDiQbQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYVL2Fiqaancnab6J0PmnZmiWI8EK5UbhfUCFHZND6Fk4jbbWMg@zjNOlXbBgFQWlt9aJ25PIic1m/vLtsxy/vIwlMHSsrlSZUCvKL9lNd2xzAcBm7WFlLyvVY7CIHg2SzEslElqPRYlKHjJRY7LtiLK5wakcjKkjt6OVlBIgq6HPR6tmEb5jIxmI@qaAcODCDThiNpO6KkH8zVo/FI5A2FknAFKMSiQBlWkgEhyqNnDlBoMPjl5wwm/F4iNjQtK/xOyP2ISwFEyyefAf4d/NkctrbvwbpylqOjqpI0ubaCHjTyzywTQ9f41pje6SxGjDcQg1gtG37MyOcjRsD0p9JuTWDGdF0ECEoDMcelKvaBAwi7mhDmCBAvx95ihCO36gLbcKE09TV1DmpJhKDjoPTXjU1Vxs64sNKquWMeQD0HnBautKCjj2J7lJil4AQ@Dydnh8TK88gnlaVaFbzpTrCwNJSDKRfWyOtfaA5PSQvaFY4lbA7QFVU2UE3UIlqe6wFY34XKK0ONZfr8MBHJ5hkV3GiMdQaa1zrQmUPNQYslGcDoOHcbMF8RwXNAWP55JFtGzeabRpI5NQ2oAaGL2MbTCGfR15go1ptL7v1MH3nIQeKzQTLAdoGsU4Tt@W0WNowdbNrsmUAQNZMpThj7xloKgGdz4XpJXO0T0SgWtc0RlM8qOJw76COKBdyvvatIGSa4FNXIGvY/EqPAR6o88ne@20YIeR8JgPl93wZ@viVDGCZriMGttgYQJhsdeQbbMn3qtUbTRiUkD/4LBL4yVR5x@TzegUGVCiV6OGfKGmwk/MQ6OdeVNtzzav7NmlIaMoIzjImag/KIPRTUR3ebaCG4algDPVIMYF0psHH7YuC6zI9Ibf8iVOy0zddJf0m1XMY/oRQX0hqTHLSkcVIOpnEX4miWLbK0m31Jo1SSmAGqXzaG6ghtdUzmXQJuksQSAIR2gMlPAmVUG1S8/xkwjgdcs0B6IttVdf6mrtHhjTdQKVoPOB7sWgPHCM40lQ3JGYyY8GNxq6xFDe6HH57iEOdE1LpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHjh2Wtea0DfaaqMPKq2uOhKb/oTZsQrIRPpP1/qxaboVzgjXOvviJ4xpvOT7W439vY3j2vE7XghC42j9ga5gUdaWpgAw@QlFe/01YGHs2Gbf1/Ud0RBLOSS9OrGagBNfEbuCsQOxlhAIL2B4H9cHUq1Qt9ViSZN7/UABuIqAuGZAo2M3HkdIWkPwAwVkkVDiOkLKbnqBJQz0VxAmbOtjdPPiH04kMN/JmXtE7hgDxwrU7E6WKfzG7XRQH/CDsxR8ncROpI@DcxTMVyAmbf@CLDNRc4F9fCuEj69czMU3EzUX2MeX5/hwxWM@uqmYeaA@sgIhwxWSubimIuYA@phWCVNwVWUcV6S4h5ZURF5zox9M5OMuEW5cdhmjokUYEeQBZjl39PmSiNNA6@uYR7LyRCxG8YUUlmzDtGcdQZBfPuMSCwSBfuhY7ZQ7dMcockEUSdBm@AKLH88ZQdYbSgN65bi0XkggiiV1EGByYZw47yc2p5Ka2jjYB@ftmtUbIAIGgS7thQSj/ES8Cb2VnGCnyPIWtE1rFOjLd1lO/L4mxEmgd@U4uUkOod5lT0Ryalveas5EHO@WfAWnccXNgA2xgIPtwgXhKQzq@yaoYvuaQ@uqQckY8qcMlyHJm/dMKPjSOCY7tj@y5M18w6kUREQyG8TqtYnT7bGrkUnJecTio@hf67MpO6C10s8E6EyhZmP4WNFvduhnDsCasMnBsIiLTEiVF7iugGZDE@YQ6i2BkXWBkAG1NENJH9MD7QzzyjNpMZkoTFPtDEC9TsP0D91fAEuWigTZaTa1h0CBLlh07zm3kscDmOJkUysp2ZtPoYUS5lTc3HG6d0iA0H97M2Y2NtEU7sB2IZV4/qeftaFJZhusp4xokuE7GkBJ4pbOg@0nkqKHfua3NcFcDXRNIcKQ60soWwqubCi675iPGnUalkz2FLuPurxobmBX/IH@9gjn8ZLbqj5oq95zfiZE4kljHk9taH2qETxxMkpT7weST5kieXqazumm0iYsfNKlqZTIxtbn7aIO@fQjoN2CdPqKcnoWQzZeonN7A3fAf3FV7kvtqln4nU@VtUkmy@SVpqymTUdpauojfGAr14O2mbSuu1RpLFphDuy4/k00cCU7unLNnQ10zicAr6Ktdbuq7T0fArvtwTyCJkDpW3o8wiqersVIe1Yew2nr/PchEG9fjO94mE6aTj/fwpDEIi3oNUhaXHpPBsikTRFWV5ojnAj2vp2zMENSYkHwVFrxeCaHo66/zjJe5Lesh9PjUE3pS6X5qfmiPyfJvElMmi/2J7kRjOoslv@/0OthLNP6ip7MtgPOB8W6Z2Adu@aAklUg2dIVB5jJFc2h3kDz0c9jDI7DUwvZaux6hL3HxfGW2x5auRG9VPTklqlrDnZn/SExOm3sHueJ2y7oZ5wUfbOEbZNe7PSSvmu@JDBbLi6bPMBoXyHZ@IoFrgkFOCdlPkS0lnmL3we1jZ55o/Lf@aPdp7ml@goZldSJJbTWXAHabn2JU3HpnX7m0/F6brnclj43XCwQTM4NvpaXHU03HZik4@9jpAB123H473wuDlJNU4wk2bGD7vnJRKEslhJ2uwfaUtG7pl4odtMK/DzY4AO7g5JfPL9W4vkSS5a/LLE8xcg0ZPF8UNRfp@3rL3ECGbttXBQLOB8ZZ@eJLbGY8nAFYUKBK93zK7eTKVLKVJpbTB5qALvVu1VG3vMnjCYPUdcbTawRKdqg92GCUhEcrs2V75@S28rjubW/TiTNoF39UiUCjXutqzB40e9Mk7JsRv7GFHIm8/UCqqMP1IE6Vz4dNq9U3Ov4yPTj6wuVEdVYErbFNBAPLYs@1CcxjfyqUuO4jb5HBYyia9DJv6jdzJV3FujiFs68j8BxhI7ZhF1jYE007sT0zTh@nHI9y@vZZnuikBjzrRKp@GUdakJdd1T6PqTab/dNmCybfVAbjK9of4GUzCD8dwIxhYwVjQlrydzs/ZVz0GVB9YAW1a6dJBrKv07oZB@a4RNwqQQzNkN1R/j7EKXnCdGmaerf0jIgS9sa7WnWk7iL9UstNKPmiE0UbGzLcNAu0uw8ZMXg44yYXAL1cCLtPjJ1DtqmHpkNztjZHxmtAlb3L80vYaQmM5Fjtzz3QwxJ1hA5VUytPsqOXAs1m6qu8MewsPIYvlIq9yg@X@sQ6i2t0uDKDl/LGS@zhadEjzUCYmltmJv01L5K3keUeqV9NXC8x4NAQxO/c6JTaVqZeCCdpUFfN/B3Yt0ooA25pgGzKVexuypOR3RcKhWhD8lXb8FjLnH3@kpX5UceHhMdY6sE7q7jk7ixc759Yo1veGlBMr4f4HFWgI5zrY4c7zkX4atRC9pz0P@ymW2qj7fQHPrFTp1Kz13n@YK6Z/TMntFTezZ1Dt/3UPcAjnT5YZXHKgHl7ynONW4nJHk0ns31nCB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@ZbabTwK0Iak34R3pDQhQjy@aMKDIZuIRGP3Q32npw5gZHJM17TUJPkeAtXR2MN/5xuf9w4jDjvXVLvN90Kg5U9xtaauslsNinDlBBei5xuSmrqp4I7VR5R3oIz3/BrTVMu0v2j36Cqma1n0aFj6wKEfMvEmO/Ntl2tsh0r6NcyguXwbCmdZtWs2Wz3tS0VqqopraNdpz4bDvY/OS4UwppprLLmFwSldA1rZoxQyQSUYf4KPvYfGv8Caztzabw5se/RlwTC5BcA3tfIlA3Q8lL9YrZ0TTUM@7rPy9hM9sm4hFncf5CZSoFFZTqoZ0ErkBy1AE1vKhPSiVcYHlJ6pelNhAgtr32K6FLsDyIinBXY4QPg848VDgnBXyDeYFUZ3B10n9mXG7bVBp8KfuQhrXTy9xZeWHN28DRiaoesrhnjMHZX9ZcjH1kTyjy6KpNJi8TOpDh60buma5fBfluxk52KZXc2fhRrNn@mK5mmrHb5Mga4vaXZ908Z99aBCJFu26rTQ4o3Sl0tFLnIMswtSOKmzMbAHO7cKsxsI5ukmkyNc8u2B2lVwn92@hlvudGd20APM03sJvgbx64HiaK8HpqvOxTm9p@BrUL5Sulprd6IVPIQedcWmLP6Y6AQYNNsQtz3Noe3NnmN@x@FsRsvzs5HTRnX/mN3jhpCAXiR2mbLkHvN2o/oONOtjvDI3r0mtU6zMPyjoNJcMpuI5t57z9188ZkW4HfStgSMe83Pv42GFoOW4f03hzq0GUjD5EYQu6ym6O9@6HDCegj4lRsKx8yEt@72mm132vphhoH6BgEOl@wHG2oBx@UhxoQcYc5iV8v/KdUu0TSS5UuN8BEZQcyypGZr7uB3GdRWYB3lPrBBXtfAwTnoff1PPvhVD8nQ@VfYflfgwpI9aOsxsvgR19O4LEOrml4eWLyy7wFBpGgM3iQcYHxsiCo8OEWtsWCwEeIBFX2@/Oot5rNDttfjmxpmUfIvJMZ2e9M/ZOAmxPRTCNFsc8nNS3knaMG2lpVM33ikMFsazQAMcvl3TTjGCi0aVeDwWC/FEuATSNQDMg6KzjHjOiR@TdBhQySVYrcMuLtjS3XAtsybfswqT1iRWr3Os@KFTN9tDiw4iHvPkF0tKvbIUSSYjS5FLY41lIj64qoMgmAuuTMB2NHrw8o5JwAyFb5hGt1fjMj/H5fTojCQovW1Qns8MsmmhIs5PI/Gjbqe46eJv/rItjo7CDNsBrRMGYyAInpw2@2rPvH3K8xW51yxLwaOniAPkts4PQiU3awwECmjZ/MSoecvOdk6L4hyaOKYNniOuhfml4I2Ldh7cRe7yxuOl8XcEi4z9VF6lgH0HfQPmNW2356TYiUYbxAf2eD8muBDMcG2c3LUTbI@1VVzapn3/ZM/QTfOaDvBgSf7mL/npO9r9L3Zle9nTqdtAjrjJX6Yjb62WOYBSe0g@qbYpQKJIZJDiA7QUMuzYFB7DPfF0LBA4MukdiqNs@Mm4zdoJS26zCJ5Ax7M2Za0TXaodP39zkalXfmD9tPqffpaO3QnCSd8lSwVHSjAPpHyPjBWMzkP0ODbCpKWhxDP0j0Zo4mjELW8PIJHCmQxPR3g8ZpqW6DV0sJnO8frcKC7YiKKb2tk7HdenM9HEsOotnY6jjcMGjm542NhwoIOBN0aoea@rLEUH3KCVPHFZHjLEE4YKuPgpajosgCe9MMnSkH1mPWSyZAs3sIOPE1LHw4X9yoa3@ykX3KOW3lKbA9qGcZNNZXMVqs5So7JeJZettk085Hvx/eUwm0leDle362nHI@rl5fC7TPYtUN2EufbSkzT2vO2DrbulVDXz@bOjjJgk3UfKfE8diImlu6O9o@2T09rp2Qm0wr0nfnZMu6@MZQ1yEW1J75k6HZ8Gutia6nyD/PF9AB6NsiWFrePFILFYKLgnmkAFraWktMSdAdE0kfoLyeeld9RA/CyAkGkdjXkctQdDFbYhMBtSDSs/sPAQOBNpxUFW4jINZTx2IJ8wuHNxjiwlUkmsAsRKArG@klTs4co@5WFfQ7EvYnmcbE/ngiDF/Pwu/HhexbkkuP@t1NuCgfI3rzfH8ni9CeaRegOoH@ql2ant7Z8db08mAx6jJ0ndSikvDgNw4Yw9jdvCvJO7dCJLJERjYEViEiXgXjGY0a0vTdW9VaFaQji2@jwxcSiVXwqNGRMoU8Grc@plTotolEqAOkgZqzV1VqGjDQNF9MboALo7XkVfCOxIPmqv4ClJYA7TNSYp/HjVQKyCXF7XOyIhLuR1xAmqPwmvx2HVcIyGeQalemCo8kcdh8F/YFTyXNk6GzIxnMl1lmRZ@OoqzLF7PmyszMcotsQJIS3xskt@efEKDShT@0qhOTntkhPHMWCU1hULz@sL6AOYB6@xjwOTTpV5wsTXL25xxqfw22KoaVsK1oZOqxkunr33xi3Ct7dzUkHtjKtmJN@DPDcwcKACoMDdLdtDmMwBs3VI1vNbIDjJTXHhgDdUkpHWEQeMfS3BYTeaQ0ZcbIQO6jg6SEqsjag4XpxE5wlZTXdAJ2nD8M2vGSLlJEV7u/kG76TBpDDwZMpXGRNMCiGsU5k9gA5D6W0LhtUPPPESwRFmJ4Azsr6YTALluprhXfSzhrZmMsKtMdce4I6IamQmiVeENXIle25fDwDOuYrjUk3/@E//jF@/cemC@@fCPcxsgO8Pha8D7n/ixcgy@P6Z78uC74@47/s0NtnsnQMie2EMfnAjPPDlM2mmTigTvNuOqC5@a2NLv9k7Yg4ZxLEt@8ow0EwoYZDnNAPopfWBKW6ojRGc5zBuwjGe6MUbYBHgK@APVG9Qo6H8VLsexZPna@k0Fhxn7SnaPa0OuTWcDqJ/HOAFLKCEpQv5woqchkImbzyEdBq0i9t1OcJYbA1kYuhGsyofmi08lsEkp6XoaqVQ5ryRXlK@z0kf/IIuAWyITxQuGKTBkxx@CoirimTRJSUuxzApDmQROYIyrW1yVgNtMEoOAIlhsOEdegN10xSkAj421KFLGtPImwA18aIttOKp/BoeD1ESEHHceE3IdHccb8DFEwyBDpoKNoN0jmAnCLYmzWPWi@/ZpXtp1MV1MQwY75dzWNcA9z@ec4cM5yw8Hzt7eUl0@uoRrA17dmKYuFF7B0rLotl0NpeWC7EAh0oCFZQXu/pnQAmdG4RFS9WuTMupbW7vvTg8Opm5hIMgI9NgERaprscvk6nERd13RPxyTxJ1Yyd98mpjxyNlsFTjvQwIMd7QMF3MeblNl/SB3M/5zufZvCliJiM587WIafUwuUP7fWaxj2PTAcBNvvFyJtdo7O7@or5evTTCM9l/nncxUTi1jMwFrkuHriWKTBcTi7jn7ec@xQsPnZR30icrja/d8s8ncf84@OFrNPzrE8d3aXg7x0N0FnV8XjX1wJ5yqHsqzbOiiyR4wbzygqzxiipjUccZtkIz@1GCpWGiLrM3PYrDVj6RDrkNybunz@GQDglnbmWiC218mvlwpx5G7Prj2y3EtQ49KJ2uNUO34gSyd1TNP32ccixdc6OxkCEgpg@tzUI6j14S4YMplYsh809fOagzDlNkzYzSHUy39RC/Y4N5V2HE6TaNowHQ7ci02NiKtqV6rmPQqdjWALJo4YTsxaAPcB16HKs4WqigZSUhMdAz4hXlAu@PEJRI9dv56DCW6qnDttaFEScaS4Bo@k6Wx/dwKHiRBOhVzXk1QLOU1VOgDtg0uXW8xmIYWy@Rd1xBbvNkt/ODjXoIkGHSZmyNWy4iZ4Z3ZRI2/BqLJHzKNGOJSIrxmZS4DYnW1MkQlWKbPdyBSKaPTkcjlS14up0P5h3N7qewVjDMcBZ6jvuPg1zzTVeiBCijXCgpzWirwyiePl@rI50gPHJ7fhOJSTMsTveyiFs42tMXtHiyUHGFUBpfbjIl70olX85NioZSCU@w4zk@mJRAjieuvQ9OUBGinb5iseiAbrhxWIqRN3oZNRKOa8dYsorD9S0zWDxONg14UATMWRC0Qy6NrhKI4oVw0XQFGglDHaONj0@axS7kVKoObsokxpbQnrkJ2hRaAmMhmKNCkjVCC/oF/K1hifj1nSlxjecSZRuiSyYAam40ySk0XIN8AVpQrVn1SeBw/ljAcKqWSmuiNSalfYkBX6zPEYiAdo4U9@YIQF9x7gqohjIaoDZtta2BvHz2UjUMFQgEPNPH20qVATCZHUt4F@kmxhfdUQ5hXsRdcZALCjp5Ad525E43QV1bSpfJNFa@B7XmwyXqNR2h2YzS/206lS7fRZf0yigNumasGl3qVeR4bjkeXzKWo0sGaltPnqBF7X4JlLlGCiaoQwBKLumxMvAzKH@VJaO8pKxHl9qV7DKlAC9Mke8gwQ9OOnW3pNynl56AspSAEJsLneiSQ3fTZFIp@R7Khz1kKZ0AnrnDS1boelzMfkmLx7EMqaUGFuCH9OVJnIbNy5M0Ge/KYi6Q7vZFd5tSxfyWmLnWlxNQBK/5A1YeByyxKa/hAY@vv8vNi3tA/eMZv8Sty4x2XKhOcPIlTcZ8vWARchplrhAyUX45EBBwGAUiojehxGIgTH7967BcYEx6WshFzfjTfKYcj@RlmKbD/Dr8DPTw9LJkS3eXW8kbpiYjFx0ln/pYP7o@Onobu4yyEouENw8leUX6npWy7Os@qyz7wIf9Jp9weDkdCqeX5Ser6fSHDx9gxgGfi2qqCuKDf2IXyUj9IrrKWHV1dTlRKC4nnkUagYLFotls7ISl2aWmaZbTbsPX7NFd1tEw/zx9SnnB9B/@GQ8T@QuH50EQERr@RrgbJR9ml6uKshxfyT4zyqlsJvs3/27xPnF31Fj/m9/rp9VFfBzi4@f3r9D9Ws5/t7j43cbGykoCSMndR@@P3tVqtZWtRP7oIv90JZlZXP@P/8fiYjabXqw7jtOAOpfwk2MyOPG3CF@Z5fPsmn2Cz3WH4T@5P7UDbgXdzc4nvPsHpiYVkiuRSD4XOfk@wr6@KReZXH26@p//@PBj2A1Xs@lzG55u@GO4UAxzJzjAl/N8N@FqeB3BCvfhUbpSqYBz9T//r5C@@gLwYMxoHX6qeQ9XYRSuJiuU5HO4WgCHnM1Cvv/Xz34WCleH4U9hWZbDI/prhDMyfopP5CdQOllOS6tFyTSfeeUdBj5eWFqWs5fj9gw0NzatH9yDfKBdmRmeBCW3z1VMcAM5vhauCj/b@Pnb//1v//Rv/5j@/pS@/wEvcS4sPvuwxZgKIzB@1taezbTD/pT/OJWET0r0jiF6kkOvZuFiJdHgpfJZOBxwTNHB/2WCJL7/G@FCYe8m0uSF0qlPNMZlWC6uHD4bfvWHjQvt0TY8JqmfOZsO8xrD9zBPFrBvgQuFf6hUjl38e9XEv6MT/GPDn/JBdngKn0X4o3/4@F78XaQQEUwgs5/F30D6hsIX4Yt6/XWP/mz82zXwr/kR//Y/4d9rF/9OW/h3/Br/Tt/jH5upTSi8vr4ejsePQWUUTPs1nzP4plIN4fOYF9H9Vj9s5bBw@CzEwsl6PHl/f5H6fhgvl8U/KFNl34cf7oJi1e@TyfXvq/H4BRXvoirKuZ6sV6GsvMj08/06II6vX6yvpxrVajVZ/756sT6ZSKR79iyOHfUZJKzWLy5C4Ttsiwr@LONPy8HfrCSlyYuyHkbtErgYOekhAhi9hQD9ofCH9Q/R@NP404yeucnI1/L1K/Nw/H94OIQIbZi5Mu1ML9OT2yAyWUY9y4wyo2Gmbx7KbXCq8Jfpg1PLdIaZbsbIGLI8Gk6gevi/f2i6rw5NwGZCSneYcRFxpgPP7uHhK8DXgbyv4E/LZDJDKOQwcwP/GR0FOF1wRs/vG7HL0AWTPqigFaTkSCoTSRUiEa2eL1gfL@/us4WPUiLSuLyI1MvhtHN5meZaE8uulOl6u/v7RmP7YKvRSCMfrS/Fn8WTz@BTqcbXxeNpuFp@ermWxPbj/JdqhNPrTy@ruSS6C3FopCyErafj3/gZo4RndfEyBBPB83P8nt/e3HIXOch1eX7ux@JPGoPIRUHwAdD03PQTDgYa6O/ov334X9b/qzMWvajHGIve3a9H6RPDv1js7v7uXvxWY9Go8ETX4Q8DwI9J7u6r6CSgO3BdRGP12P09D4PfaGydI6xiHutVSjwGhA4b5rleRsqMwYwpKhbbLi@HmUys3IQQ3@yufKZ1m1iZdrQsNXGtDWYJ8nKMQPIr5fKKcK8Wy@WicMuFQrm87ENlwCOcAKQ6SquMjF4OWzEsA2f/aAaNLXSHaCTaVjt4mfxTy4IZn1zKfP7sBzUabc1uNDA89/nzJfSkCG5oqZTyEJIpfv4MnTASg9nggSmWUkswt5PT2TH6nuIormtHYb6fuIzgtlnnMhLD@Gwmg8CYnuXX1wsr1WphBdyFYixWlpb4bphoN16SY/dLaYlXA@ZpkbCIkourMQq9j2A8C6@zp1XgcAc/7O4@TNRmK/lYtDlSY36AXCrxELZSiBbjJfFXWYyx9XR1mYm/i4tcfGV5dflZvT4ev1BMlO@UinxfuVPW0HhwX26JGzxxA6Xy5EmuBHQpZsqXoUZjq3Zaa@CrEHBhGmQww0ASOCFcdLTsyAVZevKl@gXWpH4ZiayVn/GGLeZZOFIWcMkIiC5WLFGFwzCd1Dq4c3pIWPl3TV7O5hbT@eF3he0MqN@fl/FzcXFRzBbjyyDalkuler1OoZ8XKc1Ff9ip001OleSFXMjXk6jAXA07y2GLyau58HLIoi1GqxnWxlVaGy1nixAI7cqauKDuqLruXZp6a9p6@1Zrq4D9aL@2uX2ayK4DyuxObTORPTnbCMvozY/9FJ1D//F2bevwDBIc7W/XTraf773ZPjuCcAdGSSAWfPpHijpQG@rtYHCL/oZKn03NUa6uFMtqWPAZdn785R/8@Mv/7sc//6Mf//wPfvzzP/3VL/70D@D7l/D9I/78o39byuPvr37xz/7nH//1n0Pgf4Dvv4fvv/vVL/7Fz/iX/H8N3/8zEPbX4huA418gJWD7w1/94o//4le/@Cf/Er7/Snz/5fT3xz/53/j/fxR/6PzzH//kr/FHeP7gj378/T/@8fd/78ff//mPv/8PAfnf/9Uv8f@P/@rv//0v8f9/@Td//1f/w9//4f9Ejj/jjv/7X/1b/vt3v/cHf/f7//zvfu8XD/z@waO/v/iK8F/8DkK@vpxfg@dr6vWtIb/4SeX5TagxzoUY7E//8Y//4h8B5/4J9/334IN/P@rnvsePidPkLhkfB/6csc9p0J4yzz77oIDyf8RQCGafJ7FRaMYL/dUv/vlfYPAE7D8KYsjIs7BLCOzn9nOA/dd@wYKwP//xlz/78S/@4Y@//LMff/mHKNCSK6VELZGUv2AdAsD8V8AhYOFr4ABQXseF8kW2GMqCY3EdrRkhOf7hA5B0EVyghS@H8jnw4Wxm@lOvV/FzeZGuXqYvq/xTB38qXcWQVPoyjfGpNOr1cpWQQaniIcgZZkXLfGIeRysEfIehlRL40EARhyEozqPiELURZ5VKJR4aViCOQMGLaYasWsSpF848KoAXE/E0iUYRtFo23CAskLISP2aN5cqQJ4xjQJUwMCwQBh1LclaKFytbkGFluMUQFyKPhz7A80OlWqwMq4juByoC4IhvQJYAVcHSDas/gL9COAE@NNz6AYpSrMTj1SKEVKiqlFuiQXnKeaoc1T3OqN4YDtNgeDx9xth3klyU@AwQ2oIJaPyNj6GfkiHkKcRfxpdFdejfc9J3GdNDQw@JPjyMxz/FYEovAABvMom7suCbTGJpnkH0kKOKU7bwiHMMQLm4MCT5ATRMx0Nxat84eSB/KMPXfdarAQ@iw@osLS2Ba70q5aRDmEow@3rNcRUbFy1ISVpjUqEkYTBuclGXjmiysby1DL8y/G8v0kZVTo7l0FIEdYEI8/JIxnPmihmm0ntVo7osU8njBBcKj8O5gksrT6CZrrBYKErXiMdoxqpaFjxfOd0NcwhKaEKSEnKhxA24YkL7zlxbq/wgr6yG4En@Ad5gLu7ShmbAt1qlsJchQat3Sepx6AR9pRCqVsXqGZND1ZPtU0hwesjkbCbFQHO9W1nNruRX8tlcoZBfzcorhdJKIV/MgYgrZPLZrFxaWSkVS6v3UKBnICgSa8vN/Hr1H8x8/pt/MO8zPxQ/oepbNkyxo6PXyftQdZhMprNU5IqcXy2PKlAQCgpVSRXjSvroLglqLDZP6JI2at3hniAoWuguiay6AB8WWgixBQiCD2DGtQMmFrT3DstiZQ/fD8FX9yQ5D8wQC10CM3BsIWvqE8K2ewIC54nMnfnC2JlB5ykeTzqALKAlDLaPmyhdk52afLPehtoKrYuDNdVQiFZCLoCu9RDev35RD62n/dj5mDZ7/K1pm7YJau5Ph9lQjGsetaXhbYgt14/aVfDOI6evub0HIM6sPh7EUe3fGYbtfhMKiBZPDrABP7ZumvMAVtnZ0QO1fOUfd8QlRTrvCODHe893TwPP0@3a5m6owDYOD7amHnkBlGf72zunvneVx3pJ8z6Kd9v7@9Ne8cCpyiLLryYSICLhB58J@tAztfS9ByKnHh58MwnWOOGvDBh2dNPpqn0G/VbGN7B1WUPN5tlSSQaZV8D542qmlCvlW3ZlQ44fR@XYoCg9XZRgepper7YU1mXF0CvcSwYp6EyE5oR2YT7Tx1vU8cC9G7LVNsxtbg067tHEdyENLPZgIDwwCJ221u2BnLs1PYBQU1EYfL/1A@nV4Md9PMDleVDYTIw@BxxXz7QOy4RSZPvKlor5YimXLSaKpeJKHqZ9@YScTcirxdVSJiFn5KJcKOZLcqK4UsqtgESE2HxpNRQGqaF10mkQ@LIk0VMzWnjT6TpeGWumetVQmJsOYJTFl/yFFT9gUGRSrniZgXRSCPfJMq2yKOFrNDP4kkpAqLAWC@/sbGZ2diRpAz1o59vMSFIbPfliJrO6IUkqxWyC0M5KksnTQBSAudyTyWxsStKAI8CzmZLUQ892AdVTSdLQs1nb2cF8rtCTxfQAds1juEf3PKsAZqAnlyP9VpI@@ugArsYzWqGSbqMH88SYHR6zCXGS9NwrTyYDGI45HMew69W1VpOkPe6p1TDmBVU8z4v6Ej01@kiSDR7gQUnqgqNrw0RckprgRE6UpBa4WiMFwvrgwmN8hqtI0ogTCEkkSUOCVlrXEqhSIhyz2d3dVXpuW@3yz8jmzxYUDWK04WB7p/n8ebPbbdqj2vbzY4x58WJXuRoN7Ga3KZI1G/AxIQ3EXPdH0x8o416joehzY15CjDEV0xg1VCxbQ/kIZRKfLmbSb7yAmBcQM2/1hGODTx9Am/jZ6MNzQ2lSjPehGHoOm02pjDzqjiwVLSzYZWi/UTkY0ldatllGF@jebDESjSRGF3I98alMMazPWDR2lynfI0gnSm/IQKkYuxtdDCuZOujbchlNP9HF/lNJLuWltUXlaXSI7oK0Bhr3ihRbw3eLmJ0IiyTlpyDYCqvS2jI8padSDpzDaCaSYQx@Yher9afSKiKRnj5NSlAS8AKIAgml1RIiLK3CyF@@B2q4IFybA1dtNKLRW1W5jsV4jfj7iNj5@Xnsju@w0qiGbrkTHSaGFV4apsXKn6Dw05jaKgxwg5Zr2hxfF@r/6WlmjSoJ2RclyD2djq2jNEL5Ac@xRRvt0r4tO3SOJyPoVKS3hYaUWmctdIrqH72rj@F55ia@3oYOy8K8gl@sQC@jUUEZLIVCVaELnapDN7Wr4naWVjJ5PvFZXz8HODx0i6cRDwZ9tsFuKRc8m@Btz25UNgBlpmzgBQAqepeG4WGo2lZcBWZFG3eDtTUBe1/uVi4QwWf8WU9K59Vzqc6C@eZXM1CqM6O1vn7xuQ4KIdBzFFYqcrZYHobp8MnqSjkK849YxVE/crXws46WwMVGJcMVxCVn0L/ILBbkxF2ykbzXFcddklezaxeDpYukXF9czHzurkvvq1IdM0e9kf6C1koQ@WUI85qDDxLhjvYB4tlakr8dRS4WYincI98wOw16TwH7EBgLxgmtMgzvugo6jlzKlgVIyBJ8E5VYFF9txDfrRCOR1WwkEouUAWoRgon9YnfELRHg4cgT4FwYi4B1S1mIt1V3AGoP9CivmH4JuLpckEPh@1Bbcyy2UgqF70L3d/frVU@reMlGIyWe9LxPGOvGYeaUpiUYXLxZJFcyVX3GapVa97hWFqC1TZrfpEPskh8BS6YXv3WhJ75e/Z4/L3GRD7IJceLQWmh6PV4le0BIkqSw5Fnpo8U8TIrQ9PBDmK4TZJt3nYFBVwysvUJyKWtcT7qox3440PS7Yi5ZJYU7Cl3tPhxfT@MCYqqaJmK1Dml9PRQ2TOFEm60LXQO6Zz4v4QxMZdZJ6fvV74vfvzo7PDvcYc8ya8W1IqcE7YN4lkjIETkClH0GWoF2vB0KW5/NvPyD8aIcXrMiuZVIbkKfu6yIA9BR5IPoBS5rwLd@AbOregxclYr8VF5d0xyx6hBdcwaWaseeyoXsWhYG3FjYqeLxzOxqGKiELrmwGq6HOdaV1Ri4yWKelcPVtAiWV2VIl@Q@YPR82AGuKL768Bmmy@JtrFqWXOm0KOrS/fo9/FfvL2BGeU8Ty3v6x580/NxzAPhHcN/DH@NPAC4IM46v/5Bc5//r9LN5yAstFaAZwh8qVWjt7xvfN8KhcClSjacj@GZxsV1DzNNQs1s26E91lvHv@3HAsuM4y74PvOvLLF@VGVOX0@n0Zex1FpTAUqlQLIRDv579pJdhVrm8UGMRfl0Pl8F4WZ9//Ccy8XokNAYsLyS3Tg43X8KcG4SwauDrLdnm4UEKo/ANjOPzWy1dVWx9JF7BOEIolN2nm0f4kvazrSNKc04n9yiU5vwil6W99pp4T0nihsmpHC4k5dOZlbScZ3JxLbO6li0wBeSQgyf1hWsJkzKq1qZpjbjqHt2MUeKFGsJg3L4GEyhHXWPPj/YpBR3iX17Y2n51yA4P9t@lvFAefrq7d8JODndOz2vH21CPV9snTKqdsL0TiZ3vne4enp2y2sE7BtHHtYPTve0TRJAOoQxDVYITzNej2bozctKoZzikTE8EO2brWnUnwxXbUtJ4@@RksIEvp1DxBvfJ8IEBs9B2UE8/qS3wYZsheqXdtkN4ZFBrsQVU0heWVRv31Uq9jLPK8oO3nzJ2fpG1Vg4iq6yVOTBy66tMz4g/pq/0c8dscXHx0pD8ASBYDX@aEAzCzeYQNi7T3vvthWhhhS3D5CC7EhvHHBweLWQ838L58emC7Mcdby1kfc/ezkLO92yDb8X37ZxvLeR930bt5UJhnOxgc2HV921tby4UfR8w6UJpjPNga0HOhDxi3Zhae4FewBXd2dvfZssAFCtPxKIVBh1TwUCI6MBw@P0NNC9aXr7tmQnSMpujKei2@iVoD3wCagHVlAukaz3Blk0LfvpqH4AhWchX/BS720oIrHhTCwwrobvQAlZoASsE8At4chjh2GKFZWMMohc6fE07ym/uSjDpzKHzgd85bB3VhSowQ4KufqFzopBCFW/iCy3cC5TRDlmqOrT5lUBBl2aSLcVieLjs4Gx/n2cGA4Nt2lGJIBl5pDk4TQuwQRXhF6sOobxxeLNQWyCtFoRWgW8LDN1PtGZoujWRFFDPhYUWIJik7o2iJxjqXwlcK0W86OGb1gEYosGdARc/VReNtrCuXdVtUYFiSMztwx1eQ1xtrbDJVo4xzJQoRdF8O/znz8zzXbqTXnvSa0Q4boGcF4vj4yWtIGwMwxa844wEQUe3KeUCckw8DqmhOhQXqNcCEB2@/KS3V8oqZJSJsCdPqBzr4CtFKAtMF6ccWRJBEIEgGJEPkflFW6TixhbSy7gZgr9qG4mI4wi/DLI58m@pAMk6XdCpVvV7od@cCwZMXMpTAllEddrY1uDOZRvgR/EInJxgTegmCeZFygWMxIlGgqkJ1oHgKZna0AzgXNUey0SPFaAzUusfbPEW4leyUDgPoBqD3FujBgNh8QS7LzH6wkLThulb2YMCeUhQwLfINFEkBId7PN3xFiVb5v0F2RJTf03KvZ01j494amAHwWlEVpzIcF4R1aXA6hhoBr9Ahv23Aug5S3Jk8biA8LlMgG1PwiWTHO7e48svVGJ7uhaL31wLFMsP1mL7K6vxm9UChrUxi0AtQMRHAW8coOlnsjWz81DAWEgoqDY/DQUMoGNegj4@geAr0sOQO06f/Pb0MEivTXdl6LfQglwq8CST3taktz3pxe4LIQqDKUF2hX1mTXTJBXDhaWpWBEeby8rJhJ1JL9khKkz10nR8CcxzAJ5DUcnBkAFnhTFKkJSDF9crfXx9SoXVdhp7B9unk7GIL@U0RMF7@JpyyiM2CSYKhPFOFD0xv0TRDhKB65vRI55HgujZODk93q69SkD5Ymx93AOmdQD4ET1hogb3Xg4QaqgtGI/bCRY9qbHlGHuCJUswYSxAz1dnoZuOCqgezLE9sLKUVYaD@P7JnhTGHhmak5UUZdEY@3x5CUNqZpXJfetzrp8zVnNtNsqtorLL8fg6iJDynoA54F2TKxsICeyp4H0gczO7ymTYip1jrtoDjXuYsWfxU73ucWyjYdE782mZNClzyvSme5Qt4oYMGBcnVZvHtUgaG5EPMBS7MYThcE7Grjjp58ieFOspWLwsbfVby/IljXayLElelnXKdLYMvxb2PpguhabO9dJFI6blWgoefRWRhxYaU44wyA6FuJElcN9U1MRXVrixNbonBGVKo4HXEzYaUUfVO/i67IHdgiEf1WVHgOEHY1M8kjoSOiYjBXlQf5qMaGt4VBVvkYRRZwohvbW7QrfbRSnHUMgvmeOqFpUqUAy0k@HLXYMZwgR7wg/NikfIAiWOrQmteEfB/uAhu5i4IojjGDi9xJxgEM@zoT6bzonz2WZOHN4ENy@Jd7R5TtzVoD@vBCAYHogRhxPnxBjm4bwE/IadcUT9IkDAiyCB6/VobH7TQ7@abPHAFUlE/1N7oIr7fvYOAywIyqXgwEBbh7dUYNqWhheBTyPyj0dDyugwFjip7bNVbMxJitPStGn0HiaBiI4a0l3XbLjW6gHW7@RsMZYIIAxgxCv8@or@EE4WQAolnIMkzN8Qzzzzp@OjRhacxjtOn8KLBow2TO/GCUzrEXiMHcNi43vAC3hHlB/jM/OcLjdGtzbLOBSO5nlsfnniNq2HoL1KyLEgQX/T7JPfmn0ykD/2yZ@UdYVdTJajHg/41yBgXEevg/@kjLxST@YW@6YaB7lGVa8fYF@89SSQDb/tYDJbH42QQD5PeVUh9BjwlUICcQURfYN8oeYTZ7HnpR6PP8sVlpT9NFzijXsDmdUDhQ/hPQ2NBl5w2mjQzXaNBlqWGg2J50ADLw54wUFXdDYelwIttWFSbFRKKlJCSiZrJ5t7e0nNkBL8buWK5LimrTbwgiopgWuOFYkEVgNheqpuVSSxAUxxGKWWHs6jFsgDKvjlTAiI57JnUCbjm0u/nF0rWCXzK6pkTmU2vk3xK3I7ptzw4PhjOdn8WjIvo026OQuvIrNVDQUNvzVavBkZr5iYuNkATfqiCDxfhyx9Dt4nwYtEjwaGibbGixno/dMVRtY@ybtpRZq5GEX0djT1IIIxp3Luk47o3TKMbt1qq0LPIvNQShrfuCgKlhI1DfC7p6DxiyrGA9rk7SuivAnPNumgGXOqqGPBYlpY@QsJL2eBBjgyLfj1L2gBt39FC7jxkhYM8kQduPGGFkzREQ5xWQu46LoWeAJ7S@PbIfvKUOsP0HATvAJAaHLjYuGQjzWhUZ8iJ6UfpyhCpHS8Zjcq8Mbi0poEVXfoapjp62EQft4NMbF6aFbI0n3GWMyA6jAP6dw7Z2KJ30IjBRQxFM2OKA2kTUhM4koIpZXX6jD5DPCOJ2JQfZ4KM7nVExFBTRJ@@vF4FbhhpjIxvUCKwOSBF2acgFuZgu9wI@U@tuarIOMWC0JxxW1OuXHz5oMFD2LwFLVY6JGZ1P9v5knBJvkvdKr0//2kaGbq8zueyjwyhfnm2cpvcVrwXxX6/6rQ/wSF/remzT@gkk@jnO3xU@r6F9Xwb1e/SOaNYNiwuzdoesv@FD3st6QIrH6THuCV@kJ@TBf48vjsockGh/WfOEqHfp0@bRfOd8xarXbal@3j57VurVc7xst8NjL78fOrlY2t243nG@3a1lb3RXfzQH1drK3sWy/fFt8973z6qIL2vnv44v0n3Wr1Qm@Prdtz9eg2pxad2mDwcW935O5unPU3T/LvVm8z23q@s6F@3NKdrVenb1@ePs@fxG8/vjh68amf6TtHnYxS6ud2XxXebI7OjVD@Rjtr7@xrh/2T9vZZtr@/pb3biW9m9k9Kr@XM/vbt@9zmbTyfSe9ZLw@fH59dNbff68d7@@/amx9NpfDx@tbaS7dLnc2r4zehw9xreffj4WF3O1t6vpu@3epY7Ux2V7fzV2@PjzbO3u32Xirb/Z38Went1eio0Hv9@sY9iHdXzguDV85K3Ki9fp19aTy/udk@DjUV89TOqefma9m6vT0yS/1V9eXBbrf/2paN9GH@Tfykf3q7tb2hf1wd5s7enb@@XTl5N3j1@sX7w4x2ctLcVgpWs509uTpdCbX6ub34zdn2WVF53j5/3b/Z282/20q/6qkHtfaRfv28u/vePDna36vlnIEh72/e6O@e965eXW9t7unm0bVu1FbSef20/e7wMHT2QmtuqbtvnRe1q967dH7jeuVdvG09P7361Lt@sXFydljMDo9GGXPTOW7udoZbx4VsMd3SPx5/6piv5LPX8cLN1Yus9q72yQ3lPo3ypX39ndo3XsRb3ffDj3o6fibLm@/3Pr17d7J7YzdrxtnHNzvHV/artnHoHGaOX7x81dSvi@6V9d44OZFbmefq9at4RgkNz3YdaCP1VMmvnvb3X1vDLfPj8d57p/ApfnN@nVO3ro/f1D4eZ5q3hvXWsPe1/mamfajU3pju9mD4vFW6Obve1fc/HjrvQq@25Xx@x@w4G503K6W36efxzvXztxvyyTBzYBx3Vgr2wZvX55q23Xt79um4ld95YxX7rtF9/emsvx3f3h/2PqnFTFM/eXdthM7yJ8dH2VvjpdZ3d3aPXxXcw8z@m6P27kiuvVblW2N1c5TfGtqF3PnWW/vd9a5hpd9pHwdHGfUm3n5nuSuvtWan9UZr9V@GTl70zg6O3tzu5Qv2876hbRwVMwf7u5sH3fbKy9Heq8H2fvOq/XzvrfrWOi1cZ7c3zgtbb09y7un1S7fUuunnjorxU73vds/ioReD3mD16Nz@@Gb4fqXWb6q5Y/2dOVqV@5svrOzwTW378FP3@sgyD@Sd7Ch9tm9e65lPp7efdp1CbRQvDs/cvumeysO8/DqUu/1kuS@sF69PDjdeHL5/oaxo2rlydfKmncmdFdNaz87tFQrP5e2dTv9jv6TKn7Ze5ZRcvxd39q/T7c322Zvza/2q/7J/1QoVS05rY@/9QDG3m1k5826js51X9zf2T2X1rPvyZGXrIHP0tn109nF42t58Ozh7c6hltq9elPa7K2@P35Rerr4/dU6Vc/PtS/sgNCzmTEculPK3uZNS8bBnn@TOr0ru@5dXhQ39vCm/2Mv21R3NflscFa@tT73b7u2Jmml2n299VI472yBJz44ySn5wfTA8CeXenPZvVq2N@Lvr1su3hqwXz7XV9OnHq9J1r/fydqu1cl779FHJP79SSyc76aa@k38eP958fXTV3Tr/VFxpZzb23yhvh9s9913o9a62dVU6vz4cjuTXOyejfi1j6Pmbk/P8zam5cXK@e1LsvWranebuVQ9kQ390dnU7uNlVV3vD2@LL3tUbJbP/trhpOCtHmdALda/fPj59@bYW72TVkntz@O7AOi@eD/OviuZ5yTwsai9rnefD14ed7cyqpZ2fDs@2e@mNTa1fBJlypJ/Zm4evd9@fv7AyoaxR2Pi0aeZXP8Zvhu8K5@mj@P7gXes02z@37d23mr3z9ubo7cuT2l58rzl6fnStHL7bzp8cbG46L@I7WkEd7eZundpmTu@YIae/MTwY2lYp9/56vwsjgdkutZ@f5s4Np1br3O4VT7ZrtedOc@@FMhw@76zCGIGf7fM3ZiX0a357W4hf3MYfCr8PItR3uk1zCPKSHyYL0UmhEJ0UCvGzQbRFmm8//nV6OXQa3GVPbyDlBp5BE5Q11jZReUixPf82VXyZQoL1TUiuoatlWvREtOI0QBsnfDr8kr0Kj6vR@9PUoaWbGr6nBu/MxzmprfIzcaC@pEKHBuuPcL7pqn2@91/DV82Iy0/pmn3@Rh@6fDG00Gox7y1zKbra03/n3AdQICyjm6S7XLssmWx1dKXrgENvk@tD6MS/axxz0DUFjR@YhbzfUORMXmxNRXWVCneKb8g5eM50k1/i7804FFAmRnQXBhqp6D4MFV9S62g3qj6itzKo7VSI7/j8ql2QwTDc2z0ZRhdQTu0NBXVDtac2gFo8obfSml5@hleVPFtOiyVWVIYait3UXHzPaYO/zKHBc/T2vFmTew/pGKlYoOWKEWo2dHVrQhyJGaJvKhVSjPaY47kDV2SPqiGqqN5uw@Vli1DSvivGPQHMy9bDuLV@97eFegJ3W1Mn8JpAqwHQihakZ9bsv3Nok6MPVA7xxfrtt3unDfHqDr7FcOKozQM7LgNULns@q8xrECi/KPnstkzcYQDFR7Mjv/kYqnpjcl6WaN8jbo@E1sYZ9ni3Jb3HG4uO2CzajXKxUuc7CDO0dc8juJ/mCeeEJ4FSPRkTdEFsqPB54CvT8Q2aHGS2voi4Y6sqAdBuTu9oyNRmv98y7z3QMk1dMa7RVeZbZWG@YLcCjUUvJQjUA01Zfl3E/kmaI2C9Iam/DXZcUMn2m4UAxIZYr5nPDOzOtN8e0/AW9rNG@xjm4c@6dN1sRcfRy96WG163mJcTh5/K6hAtiR3cWWvaI54Rmmei5TKA4D4dkgmq4e1WDdS6MqYGoqNNPYFSAN@WvSA8s66Oy5lgj5eWZ7VI7EA7gOYXlW8GQqgLv1h1ntXDshDoHQtWZiLpmDjeFiJwppeZa1pAhI7gOBjGiEf47tQZqvCdXj4XMU6ni0wd/tnToGeNb9zFDqWi2RNFSAy7Mc7QpwrnFxpBq37XwazGrEcNhTu4sQk14kWmwQwfw5kWj0@0UwD5hYZ0k1mcqB2dEwtiyK@RIL2gPcHQnjhoDb4Vl3X4Di5O69AUidYho8@f/Q4DXp8bj7zDgcAS/luVkcE5Z/K@LAha9vxeJ/TdFDMmii9V72f30tO5RpiAm7eWNlT1KAjMBr6SxGIQJLYsWRZ3EIS/fQmCsbGp7EJeLS5GIdUFwaWLdfaEReX19ehqMkpB3xVjMb8ziuTZQPJAYhDS1SqLZpejOS/xCiYGlLlJBCvzEWQ5gpXlqOwhyAoEch4wcBWDkHzHipxrJxEXA4h9vPVJGHyxyZzcl7Nxub6@XsQ9noHAqcTZ@UVfzsWzkJijXohPxnC0PCIQXp@sESDPZQPjSADFSjwHKHjW8cmIca5TEX6mwTxX6nMHp9@a8uKd0/AGH0qO71dU7Ysi1hc5lW9Ktxi4LdcWgfiOK4vedDUO4yy9jGwOOgJ1Scitp@KhqQR/05kYtIB@5alRMXA4giBQDBARPDxagl09NtY1v32wQ@AOGfh4nRNMTrAiTENAooDEKEJiECFEA63baPUtHw6G4mKM7/jmAxhlcoArznh@ANoJ1X4vJxJjnHy4wg34xJumaAzh9I1Cgsb@3gY@3mwf447ZvYPn0IQLWI8EG/961VzkGP0qbioGf/uF5mpQBJBtfEIj6sqbajJ/DPTyF9g85AJ@GjtPSLVDCMYTC@2Q@EJzG5opsHFSenykukRHehmTD1CMlWGewW5VpuhIjhF/iWyRv7OJDr1RaiIVOPyEooBIIaTZ6XHt4GTn8PgVUe6oUds/2q0hZphgthS7zeitIthBDEPV@aDq0zOEwy9IaF4npem9AoO/yhhh@evpOPEAsEExDQqdLhHWlzP9DDwPnpeAJIoPDUpFo61ac3Dj3lUfTFTGmYOQtyIvtRgKRZnmjYQ04M2OhJ4craKkI1qaqmNEXGBsesuKYnB5kvbwbcAsk15RRz0X9agu8YvN38mVy9KLepGPnIGFq8NqWwqSX2m1VIdO44@pDyhVvUOZCMkSIBSEzK/9WH7wsyn@2Ctw0HsKadDN@HrvWM2dVBZBe@S0@0k6bkBB4lg8HenOUytJLRI58/cGT6iO2qTK@FBmPLcrntsV5MYFLruaVsi0@sXVhCI2jzyaR54rrht7mhlXT/yt5NRyHej0Tg@vuCFbCJc61GDYTHTBgzmakHVPvCZ74vXicU@cr9w9rpQJwk5qZGLAGY@fYsLcbgPZojO2DTq5QrOvgY3tzz2GeoseGin5QSdvikHwxCkNUKc9OE984hmqBzkDMYE0pNMyFyK7Og0qPr6oQMiSXnliAV2DTmEKq4BmgLQYH04TdSVV0nTERDEQiGJVjMJ22@vkBDkezOz29IEuBMJQfuBwfCqBH@PjGRXRSe84rBBq5JCxzkoRXFdNJiFBjNs1SKcBcYt1oOJp7vxqFGerISrn6WQaPwGDok64ZS4KEPQzzHsg1Mu8PLfegXp4h@EwcSxQsUxZnKDwTvSeHbGcnMsFjv8enh@wQmF8Ohjvx2Ir2cz4yDHelMUKpdBPspON7QmcH7HjiAZFtkKewak76IKqrkMn5o@2hkM/lo1Pi4f8MSr7ytUyn8E6QhyLocFhfXx7elPFt4Tjeq3L5KGcCi2AUDwNvH/eG7wBsDtQbMVwVX7GEgW5WNnFDCkh6rCq7fB309Pb2UHi48vDYViwVW4AhpC22aJNkoiD0kFLD/q0GymBCsONauM1AJorDvovkMwR7MBFQ5UzgRfoCYeqxxuchEIkUI9GIwsnIw3LSD1uehGuLKkrp/sZKuXpvkxDmvcmVywAkVewCtGYu0MLgsAzwwzNx5fF66y8LukDj0X/PNPg7CDDJ6fePFyg4WPM7Mxfq88xxhB3tYJj0FBsYiJUVKd6zDsDRxLAOwLV8uwQHIgewzoNT4SLz0aRgvhud43bwhnJCNIiaJSiIcVGrsNdOuLmNIpe8N9lTfxcgd4XEzsDRuLAnH88UkAgy8c4hDgbOQ2B/ZNDDIM4oBS8oy6nx/sPhojDP@@G4ps4xJuFozsm5gWIgM9rSe3i5edn0ubXQvRRypQfSZsuKUXFAn15PhivsgDD2gXAoFAkj7xKeWBnR@Nzbx4glZ4MUo8VfiK3ry28yG4GaIISX1l0nxD3wlY3Dykk7ps3Kl@kEttqhJoZaB@uJEEjCkYgnqV@L0wVggaeVOClawZScJ3ZS@NJEooRh35nRY6A8h3LWe84sCfQfTPn@FzvvIpyTvaq6lWTWpDeJ61rFg2Nk3UV3SJY16Q8W9nVQGW9U8YTlRWJvHrO3u9ggKOjm7f8/gUcUCRxcln6rp1g37VxMUSEBMcojxrz5N/kWedAh/y@Mu6Rfv38stKhWd/D@6pYO0TRHuR3TId4M14nxxcK0xAgI7hplL3N9TzVwoJQZ0DpmUiXjQmzs8/OHopOB@Q1bdXHG1H3sx6mMccQlgr7geOhIeiTak8Ae2CfSc5jAWI@LL5UPQgb4CIhmSc6qccdGBGPi/GsMmENHh@gfpARg1iE7AwcUX40PcmU2VKMMI4Pk/NxeEnEcD/u/@VgQUYPFgTJQWtEYqzz14z4lQj3v@nK6Fh3s4TmBnqXlYWfj0IRE/pbPuPpAVFrrC/4swM@HwjqBkLR9pRBNGyBAg9zY340OsEg9wfhxzeMfOQLfHg0D1LSDSDBZHTVRFAg8RJmA9MiKzCJmS0mtQ5R1OJtMlluakgyhPjYeTWeWBeILJ1N4jIgd8blmVpNoGN0yJmscWV@@QepsnihNc1Tg7d/YMMvY@VxyXI8z7LwcLC324FQaH1LV/nJHXm/UTvc86@2YuIN7KpjYpCTMu1u@la71tIcMHQirq1KqgPs53hJFY9pbJ/BUIYXTrkpdqLyzQqo96Ja9oGmk@og9gET4Q1YBgB3OqDxGi0VX6bh3uL@AYHASQULC9GKA3q4abCRaTbHpVfEyRxegASV3YHCd4Ewgya9Lr6luI46UtOYMN3U4aev4L3EaZiSp7GG6UND3YfUJ9Al1NSVcqOEtgIFo5PTU7nSHXShJNqOKMbFF1DT7hG0Ibj0EvamCW3j708VkwS6WNE09BEz8AqAroJvQmf0TlzICjnvFqpJO27Fog5teVBpHrGSKRVI2DtihKN0OH6nUhCXj4X4y1PX8HyHYyK72CrtTaXkE3tapvZk8I45uYmCz/Mnw1p4OdeX92n4WzzS6UBa0/iafR/z9njQ/V9A9od2fqTTaB61dGXEpFuFboRmmyurmcIazrW0rkFsiL0FL9EJaOzq0MJXkOLGABzHvbS6eqPqLIfN@EZzBgB44g6gSqGwZSvdvuIBRnNrDLMJ3NFF8@uJE/3jKNPUJ0M6eG6CjWfUeDKNMXmMjU5wiVEFiSmCxbigxkBqwc9T3PJsmhZbA0dbbQ66NBjguSwvBZ6OUhJNTKDEqtFm7Ck81@AJRcciLUM/xs5f8e@vwv1EpsYuoJvXmbdAIZVDVAvo@hVe@rKXHkcOBAus6MCAzVc1YERYZg0xGeVWAoDGMSzK4Rxu96TFcw@kbe4dotWGMuSbi70YrKIlbnp8cE/JMgvsKQGRgPdNIWPSFVjptGcZidTwZbKeZyPCY8lqFOXusYmIj3rLPjm8/Qsdvvtkne4EY3SJJ5EzVvZ21ctldu8B4h4Q1HBwZ0ky4u0cQA3TxrWZ8Y4UIL3kzcIeQxsoQO4LkNRwyGY4LgWqwTd417m1S6gg09Fy3VvDgvBKpuxRg7972m//8WLWE96aC1TxRXqT9R0T6rTU4gsxtEoiFpgmyoqDl@AR4g6OSwzxUc4PFDDJDcKaSEbThG9Q5QXlNlcQFqhzJmlISbAh66L1nU@fEmwkvHj7eYhfcJxJjCpy2b8RWTUG/TucjCR4koGVQOB7poK0L4fwV8zobJ6537thlCCxjoI8RIICgy68cDRt3GUSTL4vU84terUUF/GgR8zy/ty9WJcG4lu7gKkI/df5MLH2XVtK8PxwyYAcsufI1hPj3DgR/VIPR@Z1dJgYgehgeB6pKmYd6BbGefKOAlF0R4lYpxECBu2wDQXXHRtIu6h3AxlrDCswQWqMKmjD4/d/ocLLuwVdIIPwawwAk0kEhBkq85Rdiicyg@gbxuMYD5O6yfiBtYazbC/9TDy2HuHn6YP478eX5BEdGsNEYxTz9qVAisZomUjgb0@5n6kuFe83qO9MeafqO0MPv74P0MOv7yw9f1J9fYvxW6oIDDH0wDkOTtmfwowa313vBXI7xVOGgZnxCLX1bjr1wMI32EylprcSzKY2Lct08Lrm@SXgec4pBMUHwiHPpzyPNXDDBDnNzUdyMQNdD2@ad0K8i9sm6otRcuN7Avn4Bfqkzm3bYoymAMRcIou@701O@SGDmBhKgkGeSPTrh1lxmcrVCVDbrml/cYUFsir7BaeK8jkYo8R@7WOMewM4AlWn7YtQGi8JEirG5iUZoN6B6aaTYNj8JILqQj5OpkKqs7mpvEbE1GJ3pacJkdiR9vgsaax1S4G1pgZJZ2DXgD7hz2N9e@8w7jE4bwyy9Ebi3igNU7G9DlnbNvlGbHYkrFN47AlUeLdnm4Nuj@FFUagDIizfUt4xUbtH7RK0enw55ADvqlnztsVFx9X37cdpdmYxmOTT@Xnsua@O2CYq/s0R2pK5LSAaGCbEDquFBU93WhibtBdI0vvAdW7o4xaHcfbUZoECbCE/QBFeoSUOsj8mdpqTsTeIJWVfA5EU11X7louatcargNUfJ7NwGWacEDUA744vUlYWfND5heVsHCgtlS5Y3H1glXmlzcwtJB1DnS5kU0VTX@aRwnEr4rTtBoqDuWNpttTfQfv5ufLVa5j3f4E1IVOPKxMEp8IkFzdHg7KDR/P6ePs43qzBORVm4IDywLRxbjhKzMV8i/Y46l3KLcy9aKqMcPGUKE4P5rM3uNFobmpacesp0FR0dAARQQlIteJrZ7hehm8Lw9SvaDrqJ@YTYIdUObx3lhfDbOEqs5d4lhK22VLVtoMqq4K8QuWM4vEG0V29VcK2pnRxhggzdU/0esUhezTNFntai5/K2DzCotjqx4Fm88k2liYFbUn7foAVNntq65pg8YU5Y@xJzUgC2Qw3aXaY83Gg2GhyMG0WjzghIeP5SHMsduJM61FCQJUngInzKrNKSAAY1U@8CnKKrTx7HZpqPJlHm3Xw/RERR7wbQtiMkLZB2w9aTVIM5JVvkIHhWRcndDWH8ASm3wnWGegoi00rhXEoCScrG/ShYtlcrPBLDCeqGfBMAHHBOhkbwCi2odg@higN42Ik5pLmy@ClGWjM6gHgJIf251gB@vpEA1JO0G1ieYcOBY3tFxBN9vMo8pvjwXRwr4WtiikEpsnEEpTJLFoaimexGqaRDGLmYLOIAQ7BYl/bfpX/l9qPoQJkoOwBAYPH39HC2FLQWElFF7NP6OlUS2RkURWQA/2B7iqGag4cffS7ZoTQAr0EUujOEDQi7zvhnVTHcRrGZ2dpfBkA20sf0nY33JuAE3UQ3tn9NYyRToWowYbrm2KcZbo4BuMkvBfH4DJR9BTj9kUcDo7enoCpGLwyAS09uE3ApTNeCb5tAEQnHRcz3BSl8zbYKS13QEK0Z@LmCtxTOkB7EO7xsPGIGDUJCmysCyI3LdXmmQG3jcwB88Zn4NfxVZ8gIMd3bWqQqRj6CD/KZqwW8j0fSAAP4g6gwi2HXTWQBsQvFBzAyXYE5faGt6YqbBQ4uPHVLXzFI@ZA2cITcWv8DNw4w5@cG1@FQ5svZom4p9Jl8FoB6GwBKxnfZx9dFPP7mDfRn9r/RCqzZ@vyYDlDib39uJJAuypmzXLeBFYr00aLqFbBnRrreMIC@iWAXmj1xQqutfBdG2Q7w1a8BQZRFbvVgypBe2nIMK5NdGprbSIbzOHQ7O1fZe4wQF/BXLkCbQz6TbySpkP08o9p0roHGskBJDpGHaOcx0cvNZJwWhz4@RK3epL9uB3z@xbPiuYlOPkBQN@OhCOoKBPZLwVh0D/e2eRTpxMVXjSFZJEs6L8QgXhNibiPfiYqW/durvenfNnyNEb5EYyxsfFs6kgYGrzcwBanW9O@5itHaHYjye8qGtm9cS2Qb1jGRJ5FDxf5nXEcX8nwjHPj15pQf8aB5f9p79mW20iuexa@ojXULgbEnReJIjhcSiK1y0QSGZLy2gVxsbgMyJFAAMYMRGApbMW5p5JKleONHTu2U7nYSSWvScqOq5KHvK//wV/gP3DOpbunZzBDUtr1upJaqkQC3adP3053n9N9LqfN4OpLXkVNAWyKPTboYcOpcID5Da8WKi1rbeQK0xZsYW2@gSrLLNSM4rL8cskbuyYe9ebKd4hsG1QxTbfkWDvmUuC5lleZbNc26nUldxWhDQkpKQKhVcvx@l1eSao6ioSGoLjxLONQ4/OOAqtJc6eimTJD8Z/bqYZP0orb36yo1cj04ThMHWEdWkm4bajqLirzBtYniww/RWN1dACHNxs32jH4OrUmJlK/iyytJqzhdSMmfwvucR1Z0hs3pq8zOjQWWk08vJO3iJrlMiC5QysDLjFtxKQ8tTF2eeknmKpIJU8OdwDHu8BgCtJ8A76al@F@kNPP9XKB@kHJD4h2jJO@yLsP0HfSumv2/IF0ZUYHKxfy6b3w9V5i1Ark6uW6a4272BR86YcyoYHKvHXKza7eckg1lx/8eaQInPQOx4iD13/O0BZUDvXZagWgyGRFvvDLgnV1J47opRp1V96RcQ/EYkNWK/ugXBhhJ@jB23BnQ1LVuyP3BP4ceNiijp9Ffkm/fJcy23yZuL@3@@Ro56BxsPOVnYPDHSpJivzaoHg8LNNNmX@Ozr37Em/WjzjEybw/8uAcxxOH4iyhBH7YHgSBeAjirgvi@IsmlGyO3Uzqm/vSo/S8p747WufyR8zMk/E9aRr7HpoIjVFVCfp3zgI4Pw/bfo6JH85AckiFWq899GTAcaEyuGfCZs45uH/iSmoNKCQtQUjLBjxSBt3gHDlAKU1E35jhpOl1YDW7Jaljq6DxyiH0l6AdIiADAPmodTstUehrc63CwLvAcyIbiW3leLYgez@oiH2udpuqFdvcL@Qhm71B/yQjvScYLSDODQ6tAgbWXldDTEZBUAXqLaCnQBxp7hF3qIzyQblaqpQ/P5cG4SP2b8hbwRuY5L@hnfe8nX5i/KQks30VA8DgcWYxG7pI2KREC7rkaE1Rg7pYRUuyojczJ0@3Jpfol3/DFuQpBuSydStfjNH452vPfW0z68/sY@GLN8NJJOCIVY4i30QV09nnZ7Dzf8Vq5PXMRa6yovjSdCLZdEIGVHsd44nsYpa0j5Hz2N3jC3u8atLXP77S7pbhjGI8mdq1Ioq2OoJNVGk@jEcjNZGvp0Qf0aCPqJX/2tTh0/uaYAsQdjdZ7fg1em0YR0Q6WnktTXgdqOcKFXdTW38Wab@q11TbR5X20RR5z/AiDdecbG5URZp2m1evREQNnC1dWMeXyF9qmGvzFuVU3riMU8ro8uxQd2ZcMqb@zpeCCaV1kLdAxsji8FrREHOSWk2bRAlXqUUU4qUclVO4ZvPjF1NbD0cwvCwlJ2LmJb5sq72IY4OBqOhsQNuDXHyOIijDy9g0lNGpUXORVplcaHM2IfoF/v@LtZUmQTbw@NLI6jdoZPWl1ciXViNfWo1cZjWycLM89kflltcvA2vWE8Vz4P4zC7CgtvfE@@/dOxJH7@2Ih08f/Lb42t5T8f69J5CyJ/af3n@0@0DA/50nhzuCCuifr7gjVLkXMPXbbtul2/mlSmVFEOa5AOUr4rB5Jt4btN2XQDwbfvNs65S/lPpusMmldl66o@mAn4OGqMwSSKsJuivityZ144QW1y2g5DN8R1S@PLGN5M3T55slsr2gcOjagJvf9ogHIT0uelbSRhsAP4BUQNPkJ1nSncandWJaOiUhB07/vPYIAlP4@FDce7KNkT63d492954ciod7B/B1/2voZkds76LbmPtPMYsAH@9t7z7cfXCPErgBlZLAuzUyWL@sCSUEp1Fpv@iOMTxYD6VC@S3i1Xshk@kPlFWEL7Ljfui@pwMkhe/u7Oy0Ri7a7Vv3Dt79CnI17teFZWGQS8OhurRAuFVBoxGoTUbRrrEzdWQti1XekM6m4hZm1zJ0B0SfC0Ihz9E7secK6wFeI@KDNMXNZoZNoYaKbgJuRKUcwTqCIjBks4UNQrkJtdHtgaoNL1a76gsW3ZKOWVGOXFBeWn1CisEZd/ttDqOrEoDuWaubqg1GDIAXQjKBAfAOBhOC5gt3Fy9JxKqEGAco@EPCbU54fjZ8eI5cIxq4yoT7HAhkTbaJ542mFAMcNb0@z2PErIl3B4qRQkV8gkcnOb2eunIllTjg/@UbG77KAqQFu2AXVrYSKsJnN6AG2NtPm93AF7aTw9tgEEHcvseaWie9Joh7dC88QoOll6hGQNWuOfizqRzVK4aTAnEqEaY1FdF26HLb8uB3r1sOSt6fqxH19qjTqDAl4z9d2YD7cw14EzSAqGjuF@hWaBgQY0toBl1JyrY/AIoEkU98HI1qNOiM226kgJR17OfeRx/l5CAXwiKGig@1TmvYYagHfAg5Rx9U5OYChBjSlDzF1yieQzvag/Bt@AyVIUbYwA/V4MraTOFB1Sg1cWSlyM@n1NpqkjHclbUSxbNusN6@htpnFD1/@2yWR88kLRSTtTTnoz9nVGJAz04jdPPSFahYNA2oJRzcIRPuHR8Lv1z/YM3Z3L7/rPjxh4XjcvmEt4Vmhx8vWCmRn1lIJIfloXUnSRtQrTSJNOOPW1ha6TPybomrXCEDxuXUA@Z7q1HTeXytOp/ep3hZ0XRKfPXK4VJFsjchEsJIMuHuVhB1VWWByhyLnEQQ7p3QWPSsq1IKhFPv11sY1x5noQYj0sd9hNRrzLBqpF9jeLvGBz3YWTKST@Pp1vhzKha5pCj6sc35KH9g33fym7mygqLFpIfTVlt0QWGu5mSvZji9dF7Nodu@HB3s39dHt3Zp6/h4eC1s25die622FfPpuPhYMnBdH@3Hl6Dlw@2N0ELfC@mI@ZCcx6YpXRNn4daCovkravxwbu5o7QEaPHsxoqpGatQ27vfQQ5zNl@LQNCqQM9GEDNHh0fbOwYGwdvCWbR3Kwr7X7LfJvhS3QcR9U3k6Yjtk2uxKmmnSYYI086RSZmxeGq32ssWcOHgpW4XkQQpyPPRmoaP2gmQykdYRfLIQC4GG17whqpGLtu5C7UF@XSKe1VETSoSTZnQwk9jNBT582Mk@bTLhuBWYN/ZfeEPNzLgT6ayLrqpHUxORYoTxOGie4Mt38vy9z/zxuqqHGSz362PqMCrht9FfvjiEiof4UlyKzuAl06KmlHRWiEoX1NiRWV6Uw/7sBKVjsc8kL2xs65I5lk1j/viWEcmO@NMtfOefysz2mbzvVFs8pWyYE5oLDz07egQBkwlisNgyqQKKH8/kEUajoc9JRzPk5lq7Ra2pq1ZSNDOJu5YO9BZw8Ku349tDvCrYbS@tqvj5VMWnRKQmI@7WfA0qEzDfXl1dvgp3vBeqePGz4uYzJL5/BmfDl00DpT/1SVUIKHf3SUHlhwRwydA5IAV2bLVgYgWB1Uk4UyJ9p8PIbB@05XyEtnjQmL2nRwW8L4rXmhOTWNuSsfOJZGInkLk@GEtYd5RXzdzozy6v7j4FdbuivpuvXx8vNgTC@/DZrzhM5sFgiFslMOKjBntFBZF83UetuABLcPBB7enXiIG5peJY1jne3Ba/cKONNNe4FQxeoF6/ipwpY5tZ@AxVOmsOL17hBdcrujLlPLQJkGW9gth6zjoqHFlzqzMgJYKuDmW5xa2MpsE2/7JhBt9cR/VBymMA4wHT0QOYfTsrQO5Zx1sFFWoym@c04E90UpGTgFYDlD10@iKno12CN@xNdXqZ0zsuBp7TqRsSy3lTR7zMbkrIeITMrCWB6a7W604bNOw6@x3OBjZGJ70lGwOyZW@gU29yKupUqaS6LDsOk445CSQpnbQgofBg8gKTlnzXfdGgSZbR5gBhtiD6Xu@4JPWn3rGl7JiTJhwBTySUd/udDE0KxTzVqNSRsIWuZSUJ1be84xIpUMoNCGWycGJ5IW15YQETGNKN0JdMVFyMGoC/ZSNkU03ixZrrW8@Rwkeu3x67YmeCMr6KjaiokhyDLIidJ9ti76E42NvfiaLGFjeQR6FSSmGPQjHLhlF31JItwIQPxsFpgxPV13juucu5CgV/10D9wcgA4q/xXFUBoTjGZSkuXnVeiToc3kM9KXYndywnXfVY96HUHoz7wcWrySua3glweiUggXfErISXBO/MDYtciZLDVuRAb3EYFhL5yoZyqxDWQilUy0T65hhIi@vYms/NJLaM3j9h6mBl0iYdBuSEbRJ3ggGyPOsyviUMR/s0DLhJb9mOsO14w/BQKpXmkvPijg7c6JoRd6OVXbOSfFold8NKmMI0npKPcUTD2nKiMxCvvFeqsvBQwaN/LS7t6NFG381yGo0jhpZdBKZybGTzq4TR504m@mluwckZFNF4o/J1gxcEBnkPd3OHaTwCRvQ9B6Y3BwXGC2gOjlZBBJCXyRwglZ/H2EhuZbj0Eooktzhcj/PNSaklRJdQJLmWsNHRqQjXemw22gPgzjggCX5ogCBonK@JMwdkM1dx2mIV8YKSFEmcaXCdNv/JJdShtmmGAHo8Vh@rx2x6I7JmsUvhoyNitkB23hgQ3IPInQoea2Z6NZ5uHkli0ygehzAaFQMGnLGT6uq5YE8ikaRztNTiZUVGWzIaOPJa8miELefYACUSSgEtRkF51YSwAIogxMXhyWKA8kqMguaTQQ3iJ3gTa6ytxmrUoPlkUGN9zGEtJmGNgubjoHP7Gm2U0bHXDO2iffnk5VL4WBOdUZU7cdvjgE8a5bQC1lAAy8NktCR0xzvxgndEyGjRpxK0B4l2ZU16xFZpIOCv3tGsDxVQrLbZBFltiBB3C4OX8hIq5usok30LGXPNPEbgOcQ1vo8boHWCMKdBsAcm2RDFZEiBRp1iihUzh4ZLTQJRI2MkYYmFC/g6Q@63vnDB4g5HfrcKVm5mcbNqkV0U@qSSpXy0saHGohQMGp5I/KnJxhOOwVBEcZTCpEt@IjjGgU7FK45Cb9Dmy84C4qopYa0O6SiA08NODAe@psz3RRUENMdXtwMfVOZxYBPy4rJOmTiUUDWPY/HaOJTANo@jeP12kDyV1Je3ro2DBcEkHOVr40AKnB9Ta@ECEMz4t5VEapHxQLMomdostKKkoXE2I99a8b4oUVWgvSBhiMBPYt@S2iEZc5PWe4YYdK3xQKFjfjxsj1fSJhzFtHNX@IK5iiVzc@uFhVtK5RtYY@XVxC0/6MBBUOr29PpOWPwxET12SSIR0r0HCjGl9ukIRCSczZKUPhQDQjih/Y0GqmY1GnQztH@w9@7BvceNJ/ceoxC1wHsUXt@gtgyp61RKSxjPnm9bGqRT5AhUtcBuZGgfNvKofRLNDp0iFDkWSy1cGHAzixkorMmh@6JS3z0XDyGLgtbP4UTIkr6bgemxqQ16U7eKL61cCGmeYKpXUl7bhJYQDNOJbAnBGMkZQ9ji8s/6rKHyrP8sYMCWqLNNpn9stvcZGi4ZBYUovnwWfMUdtVCXpKidlvIsogo@ym7knApVLuQNeojBmMBflcvivnKKK@3Xmr02urwdd8nx7ZnXa561Os3S8HSY6fqOdE9jZ7s@OrnMoDLV7tHOwWFjH@N07Twgywn8qVHe0e7jnb2nR5hzCFnLMnnn4GDvoEEK6gdP94/QY2gsyTIBJZYQTCZEgJ7svXfvkQHD3y3ZSDYI8UHehD/SlU9BeMPGhH5PycyjwKoQDQrCQ2YqWJTSCiLwztzBWAVvQ/8T6oAvoOUJPspAXSqqMTmksfH6U@aFvk5nBhS1YzQeBgRKGvB2bCRy0RIMc@afYAHyReQD307a9CW@UcY8NOQbDO1YWTSQwWIZad/V9Wl14DI5nPbbtkInHXkWLtw@QOJrU3YcdItr2VkOvUoOSWkoXjhbhpOjTM5Rs8kl5QhKrfSMEcTIvHatZZTBO0CRRQlNQmiZQgX4BbEm8nkvd5ExA0TJLNhVOX7UhTBs6KMwMn7NDWOO2K0p6/lC/Ugg@pO0wNE0wl/3zUcpIjD5PkXGHHW0PNdjRn9VZ/mG2dazY9P7VGjXXULtkQfQ4HuBzY5eyGdfSHfyuUs2oIEZ8RmP5gF6@TYmO0wVMo37QQ0GKhhNBVsQ@oEeLuj5Mf6eSNeubVSgsYHgciasZXEuu6NEIyE/YAAS86xNaz10Y8NmCVpxmCE2TIhqEsQHJsRSEsRLE2I5CeLTTxjE69r5vJq8TbG0usrazJH5TCj@b7p4sahgN5QqdFgY8JnF1WnMSHYYh4TOO2gOap7ZgNxs2e1LWxZF/em/A24TlyxVpEq44Zc0@xLMP/89a51v6K4xSn/NPTQ2KGRO5JMXmzDjfeEDSeKqSdKWNI7tJ5dgsyw1i8llvxtSxAcpRPPpTyMwyWTzbTXvQo@feuG6EZathlYNcQT/MY/AeR0EDS6v1hd5G2UDXsxeWtdYVA9CBAyybIIsxUGSqnx1aZUVE181scqqCVK5TpWf/kzWKc@vBIgfagjaa@VgJoL@V2ShkWo@FEoC9RkSbWr2w1ffVPCTaBvMYkng@yF2KnJ8ebt//o14u8OSifC/n0icVMCkLzXtiQP/D9fFsZyK40NGUSymjluWIfL5VIhPfxS2g4c3vswuWyQ//8OrS1fSS/9uWDo85jfVwc1cg0IW3wK1elA0k4rWNTaePxgAnZLQGuMY1WvOWHJ4FkuDsWgHqjpbWpxFs5dU9jQxe1lnx5DPmMFSXBL61yPGaIMjDBJrFH4mK19muFTmpmNybTnukMntMrMuDcxhbDSPI01xDKZnMyZwLEaEjHnUMjcnmb1ZhrjgWqLw4zdHzdN@EwO0@oN@SUYA8QblnbPBcw8PqlEZ3VyUnvtp0tBnYa0JAclxDoqv91ChApoqnYqw7jfL7QjYbLfHZ@MevqE5Uq5Cx0jlMrqMI0GwPz7zJU48ce@PvR70wEFOLWQRQcwbQivpFAZW@lrVx6pOqna@ynKZ9cZL5IaOkqht7ZE3DKgyZ14WQJdPxKBCFd6GAatYeDRQvyBE7IrWkf155PVd24DHKK5ewUggvwh5h0vViDLiY2LgKKAGyJPxWQTDhZxx0o1xOKfko8WPXSks4ci5SDdi5GKEEG0d4fliSfqgI9cyiERaEI2iWJYKKzkeJUK0D@R5FoVYKSxVsKIhZpGLIvIMrTXLm11yW0RGrYSDsGlomgXgCEP0clw3K9A7yNDtcqxf/u0nf2flLspllUYxdbx@E2QGikgSYsWvR4N99d1Aj/KJtFWM4f77EDej7rht76yJEWoCAzUQVwpmmEDEfAGEhk6rBj3YbwYntuELRlWIhFUu39veFkfvHey9j9ZQfIlAVBArjkSwLqw8DzuVjORLxWAEkZQwD/NYVoxAqhHzULpXCKZ7TO51urahgQWj9c0/ptGiu/wBarrzuowhxGyLnfrgPSHq1ppo9UQoCsZ5@OYfMebBkLVnkxEPhpYkTPg4dIH41VWkPdcvhkiu7xff/zOqTlqUAM@H9ypnZtVpTD/l1uWFLNFssXqc2qtINTQIqYivHKJv/ZiQ@RykW22EmRvmrqiRJHf7h38lCAc@PsDsGSVFBE/@SkTfZkT69YBGLhVf8Up832F8HY9eAUxErWm0i4/hnCyN0GjINpLLVwzfL74vWwzwXoBvJpfUsRhpbiZxMv7VnFkqK6cjbX4N/Kkz/AMTqTRzTcPIB1Uink9@Fi5Ts5vsOpnp@4axOmNNS@zwJ/@ZRH2kYw6rBz2AM1pzqhLXSkqb/@IvNf5J5sbkCoL55d9@70dhHyepPZuk9ud74WqazPdiktb2G7Et6at4ZFj5SepU/DRaTWTlThzjaxqCn6SN@yQ62JO0JQ@krxf95Ipln4bk2wqJXvCTK5d8Gq7vKFyJiz3erZTlPkld5gp7ykKP4V9MaSYsxn8xF@PksplPXfPpZPE3hBwZPjQenZuWcllyOBVibTdElf6iZ178uxlvjbn74VVbyLg4wFEBOpSaIrSHUJMNc@VfxGPKz5ivCVOr0tmC6pFRS1XWAqJJs@cnVOU4n1tdSzh0IO4l1LL5ZpVkZuVy32Wj@/Gwg1IHvd@dkeQxouc/DB6QvDN@g@YSuG0QV9jahtwT1KnJx/SC48@RD6Ijn0NK1EAP0B0QN@jvhu5uscopJG/ciGPpDZglukHX6SgKpQoiUpLIV48ThQqWUxMXwj/pHYilqxZLVzhYso/kRzbMuXLz/taP9I6kR2kQxR5Dmb8a5z/KaSAVI3orJ48dkqdLR@1EvmlBKpqqjoDUo/ufzd0iVl06L2mApWH@7p/og871UZe1A/1Bk1fy@I/BMXFgUk9AY//kj4TAzi2GW0ZqzX@qJt7nHSqtcjzJrlFPSjU//gMLSTt5kDi7drWQJTGmylhi94l4erhzIPaeHu0/PcILGdMxopbB0wU9Frt5XyYBNnpJMCfL1kDMX2Jx1shj8vIKXn4pR93/8@9h9xlt3rEqljFMl5b7QaRcVZW7ZIxoKq49QnJ85srzpQW0juuWvXWcNTlCIEDv9gNcr74LHyQYX0yww2d5tjH5s8m0KXXLihnPNab@8@yWcRmTfpmARx1OgFMVOH9O5UvK@GIog66spvh65yS95jF@6IVy@UmgXzQFRW42ky98z8/PS10MTzUeeSXXR/dEPjqGKw9PgFnoD@hSE91mA@F5bZBt0XnhuP0i/FRsN/svmz4qyLwzQZVo5@7bU/6bSbsjHp6ccSiON70nFoJuewvTQrsAyAqt9otC97xTkxlsGKwVTjgRuZ@R@nLmq0/esKshBgHes@usVu9Fe9Ajbtdq9eAgs8KquYcKcqq@yu9Djw1j1CXyVHo/FcQ026xIIfDRgHLgI3BVyrrYm9Snx5HiE108os3ic0TMS5GyQjDmsx4HhQ2YcP4krFRVW59IZ/HahAxfH1ApREEimqmCiViEY86EleI38YUK0xByGklDy5@2Q6XVePM3mEdHEQbQxBAG3LXL9Q@e1Z8d9333fPE4Xz4poKMjhG5Js0YaU/LZw59x9Hsve8OBH0nqu37ACi4VldQ@ldTAtMKKL3KsYho30CytcOOFg4bagQ5l4hZ9L7A9aaZK2jin9Lxt1a1wjLlhddkYHGlPKRnINHx4MkztTUTHBiJM111SkfiSdKGs90foT0vBFmHM0QFMf4pmhBioIbpUZAxTMYu2Cl/LOAGGnX3gxrqi8mEq6rEso5szOf9m82@@dvO7sC6SW08Ey5tiTGls4sKG68rlwh4xNx1jXqEF5cVmD13@WTt9ck@jFAdztcWyMk3herALMuisMflt6XiCX1L7UgsF65qi7CumDi9LXhdqSLWmSfgKT/mKEGR53kA4gkhCMVcWm5jFQNLljYOexZKKnRuNnFAjJ1yEoScpjTyWxTCQp@m24RidtjXhPAJ8VdboJbFQ@M2XGJ@KXREtlnWd4Z5DVKAsDGFCkc7ax4m1141GG5tWDAES4hyCjtttjnvBeia@4VWL@pveo3go1R7F3yQZ8F4BBEZbcI2VymxNZPLFAq/SPXJ7CZ/qGataqBSq9K/C/62CSlT/q/OJlShkNZpYKcT@/VoSj3Fkk8WiamUFN@TMrxbEcBqcDvpLmQWhz2xBZzb6I@QX1Oc@vw/7fW84dAMKcyRO3D4@bmPgV2@ANxbo/Avj6sDnFy75F1lXyAU/xTae@w1E1JCISsOpsG5tWTDuZ8PBKBAf9byW@owxym@vqG/@1Ec3Ur7rEg/kAxMkn7lR3/doNN0N9vp4L1FGj8nBgD@3eoNW@QxEeXdErhx9WPMA4Q1Ko3G/TO6m3H4Hn8XJDKH5App2CtVB1zoNAGtgt@wcUp7vontK69mk27XIeYvb6xy6yLjh7ZHQkVR2O8R3NP1TC7e1BfEEmLB1dreifJhoL1004q7Iyse4Yo/jOZPGQNaI9IUa7xjLkjQzLFSKlu/15PrPKtEDNJSycsSW2Tk6EQdBCK9UOWUBVgyJlMA@YpA@ZozxrAh7hCFCXbQskY3ICyETqB3hV1lpmEAVyfPZKwB7iL1SVrSuDdPKPGN1Hd174l2ZU83pncJDO6nq2jrG5qCe4IDiNMmn4eoa5pCDSl9gxDn2TWP2I@/IlgAgTwgFQgQee4QeGVrPSYkUL@vg8ED6K6k8vJ5ooUu0HsV4wfurvntCUVLEecvjUDAdzycALFk@@cgbyiEqREi1NT4BVpvWAkVW8Xx/7K7eWVuhBlFcIwXaGbQjoEtlwIyuZcvUuNPgrKd7cTc4FT33pdtj/2/cbIr9wouS6MyW2ydeN9/OEenAUEZ6CqNg3y1w2vbOw0f3jna2C6JYXUVwNlDVsLYxuJydp3wy4JBkhEV4@ZZat1eYyG2/kN0qZ3Oy6VvmsOfNBisEsGeNUI4b2lmHismbOUYMIlMH96qCjreoY7uhrjYuN2zKeIRRCyw1uGrlLyxYSNJY1wKSYGRzhDK58NCAb7DxzAGl7hUwAnJ3a6AQhqGEiHKtjZvFol5T6/SpCBtrsbjJdubWA5DDX4jswbgf2W2ztHaaIgubHHrL463tZpb2hZJVE6dO9i0/W0PuXHNOL@1x7kKF@Ot3sRU2D9zR4P5UzZ89VlorMCC5evU4l5MJ2f/5bxD7ZqFZQM8OchfIX3/kKJewJd7Ud9iDpp3l22Ao9lEpcCfBA9pcAyeo6QKtQWdaopCknQdw9nbsj8w6hnbugrSb246znLuAKkdDtEMZwmboHgHGXA3TupG0UOR49qyPbnEXUf766uNH78GUH6B/KT@of3C8eKtcyGbhiCcNJAcjfYjtvcf7eJMwypXoRuHhaHAmx2XU1JWU8GEfLYep9QULu1bGVQg754kbyN7796dHzZMnzTOQmJswBNELnKap9YNh7lGX3xwjx4pOrpW7OHEI6nTkdmvMCc1856V9kqsF8OfUrGIVqnCWlgh7AIUcdCAQG3WvD6f1e0ePHznZjaZArE7CqsjmW5o4gFCIYGxMIoE2QjoYThepKmC7TSIY@Mlnrc1oXzbKzc1sbTZLbc@jQbPDHr@yIQF37HFBUtzImZ/S2iikgunQdTCBj7Z3d46sApRF2RcTKcbRlDYtdkbsqDqY3HCnoCNweogwjrPy9tuUhkXGvuMsVSo5VA@ZATbyAQFoeWGNarNR0@nYeiCbQ69EV@fuhOsi5mSptFRu9v1zYEfL1duVu8uVdwYjfDfouH77bR@2EKeJIWW9YPo2GvKTOtnJoNd9u@v18MHq5sri2p53/3e@evfw9rbdbv0W8JDWc3@AD/ijodmAUfNcav/BHjtqM3VRI/qAs90sD5svBuWVTqW9Vlmr3um4d1bdtcryWnvVXb7bunv3bru7stbq3L3TvLPabpXRbTQVKZ2R8qDF5I/Vdq9XbRpjtrZUudvtVqu373RW73bvLlWWl1daa6udyspKd63aXF6@3Vlaa91tXc61he3JwAar9l08O@I78FvpzF1mbm@XpXP/Cw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmQ15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22/!]sss_ 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^' 2                                         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&   11/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xflosgem 4721en og _e25 $91 <>60or 709395cr=B1+R(1)u8"?!"&&1/<>ca g 8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201 )#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

This language is unrelated to [V/Vim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V_(DJMcMayhem)). This answer is based on [the work](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39587101#39587101) by Hat Wizard.

Ørjan's interpreter used on TIO treats `!` specially, which creates problems for polyglot. This answer uses modified interpreter in the test driver that does not treat `!` specially (conforms to the spec).

[Standalone code](https://tio.run/##K9NNy80vSfz/3w4CYqL17WL0Y6C8WCBfT98OJKKnH6MPktfTj/3/HwA):

```
>>>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]
```

Code in polyglot (line 60):

```
#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
```

Comment: Oh I see. The `!` is a common BF convention to separate program from input when there's only one file (usually stdin), which I probably used for testing, and since the interpreter was a quick hack it's always on, even for non-stdin files.

Answer (score 7):

## 212. Strict Haskell, 10120 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kSH1NUrwWKVK8iOymbi11qyW1Lq3ulvixi2SRLKlYVV1VlEip9eHMeHHWx@MHezw7GHvWPmfGu9h5MLCDxT7Y8CwW8LwaA/@Gb54WgwXOPzgbEZlVLF6kVn/nzK4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRmRt2rKdu83vwnhhx0a2qirGQ5zFNthbUu9VqwkWx@xF7Jq5zLZQAChalZ30Fd0xy4FQkxiTNVbahv8zDGuFF29VSwIzzBmWkbXkvvM6ckOU@yWbCo2MwaOOXCY0ZmfLMvYVt@4VBOYsq/qXQBzFMu0FIfiVxg71TW532zLUzG5qQxNC@JttqloX/pfHNYy@n1Zb9sAmWfsjWHZCsK3FNs2MPkqY8MtpTWFtACgsqUae7X9l1NRRcZeQhFlU1OGTG7ajiW3HNXQkSZpdrx/enw4lUKS2LuT7e3p0Ax7nTB0tj1oXU1HZdmpZcuaPI1/hdUGjrHrTIfnWK2r6DLLJIvJzHRknq1b8kySVWYpcrujakoSGoQlWE/RTMViGMI6hsV2oUhaIV1IN2rjlMkWpi2MI6fRFpmWzTpT9cmkgfCG1VN0KGF6OlLyIqciMl5EW6UMZGvEInbPsICPLDawlTa7Maw2MJeujaJxSM@Gt6wp20p@BRFkPQRXunGjAxM5BjRtc@QoTDf0BCVGwBUm7TWmGSuTw9Dawe50eJ5l9qbDVoHRWled2bbMFNiRYY6mQ4vsjbo3j52zad4RNow2tMZUnMQOZQiibCYJn81M9oIWtC50ZnZpQ8HaCrN11TQVh0cCrygWRUNqpqn6Fe/gh5bRHrSw8zk9BfLGDov8YAdakKrKTCEmkuhgIeIgDgYlODb6ir@8NtMVaCDbVFpqR21xxlKGjqLbUGQ7yVSoxI2qaaytaJBgjL0VZ7aBzTsOampyL9lKBpAxMRfWv9KYylqmyXgU1AKKtJ0uMAWpx24hXuvZbGj2ma32IdppGZ2OorBbxexB8kDbCDD4tMypanm@JQVgdMUljWKCQEDSGEhpoJNLoRtLBtJatqCBo/aBsKoTtpki2yoKVEhiK3qbqGp6otZg8gTLs2sVOjxUfWARbluxqMsRXuielgIoZa@ZIzeW6jjUa1iNHSqyxU4sRYlOit2JLCEzA3NwsCJJatS1tfDWwXYYGpenSMomNKaVPXn7KiCzZIUtNcrwrQSD5cDW/ia7W7pAN5eywACmFZGjrPIDs1MXFwp8h1Iz1bXuA4A1AFTRWMownZScMKGACQcKmJLRia7EdSZpar6M2dpUW/hYjkO1oTVA@LB3capZa2BZOJKMiSpfQaU1Q@8CPaGy1kBHeugsn4YmaBkwEMSZcg1UA8lLbQRyASl80lOh0WxsEl/H4uMhERRGRGBjQVE3X9vQBgQHKW0HeRmoAkkR426HvWMdWdUwCcQjKl5qS7EHmoNpBnobWx7GO6WdZG4xqMNawMfXkJ0MSCkAWL/v65dUKACGhjCoqhj14z/903a3C3hqrRbINsGu71jbaNHILVNhYThkyLAgUDUqFsDFMXeeHDK4ljW1TQJC1kciCyoE5XpjDLQ2MyBD60aFXtqTr6FnQ@dqOQpncj7Yx1lfvuLSROWcCxXvy01oWMqA8qZqJ9iLDWillhIIEc8k@gOnU2AJc4uF7dT3keelyPPFCwUKF01Gl5dSqW4ZGC65TEHgCz/GOe9qE5LSdmTbUNsBc@T0DD3DEi0WbFUMU9Ej4Qkc4XjYaoajSZRykWhZrbSSHVVvR8JrwItVyDgcLbcqrXO1VC9PJfdnCWhuEA12VyXSigYDIHKoU1yn@iDNkzA4vEsIly/OsBtIcoxO@oKRMNNh1zwgRMoO8qWBDAJyKGlrimJG0kkpimIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwSa3HwqFwzF91wgA1nagodtYT1UCxpZk9HLSAKLptwkhgIe@2YKRGyWirDmiccdYkvqZRBCQLycQbJWwpOKR7fERdknc5TJ9AQSkwjLvQZE9W2r6ODEIA@rJjz0hjzbiBDKlMOMyA6NAxU7kLTQOJeUVqvCI8JwqZrBJXNABbU2GFRFOFToDdDWS64Hlf3QA8m@EwgI13Ep/s6csjwNLiw@q4wzC1A32pD@IBtKGWgjIHhI/CBxTMZED9zwYdG7XtdCKTy032sZku5lipWuIjCOnb1KM9CSvv70woaFhHuWGarHcHclfhmhiTWy3FdISggprYDoii6fGGAhNi8EzavcDSi@m8aRBxVYtxHijkeeuJoVBG6SIU/QSoMwqThakCmqMFYkkbTecOANdTmQc/IchEAT4FHyiCqwEAkylDpTVwQKoBA9/01FYPeBZLp3O5yAeh6ewhyJ87SPZEx8saCyNVn2UCyZQXhMV4EEUCW3QWDwyuiKo6EUCN7w94HLNs9@cgNrwiwkDgC02m5CTw3ldw9g3dmIMUCOmhRZDJGN4OoIkdo0IJA5erdlFn9bRMr4mgzdAQaCP/9RzHtEswTqhOb9BMAqekTqzRrnOgI7OkHGukOgZ3NzWjCWLZhv6ZcnNItQZNdThVIQrz2vDSDlyDAtaxWQVG7s8D4LpIuGODwKTwDQT2RQVJcBMK/hsEQAJKAqEiHZtE8TYIleOR3ooEk9SVktDpgnEWxI4bBHMniKk8umwYfZRC7IwUA9T0wOxTdbQVhMwnkS/PHeo82U96XTicvDRUPXIXXlxcDJfCVZDsi4vPwbWGrufoioHrObkS5EK4JLooRZxcGHtOKTCsHr4/dzEPo3VstiGOSreqGZHPS6VsPS6fS@KZwWcURB1INoBO4APwhKOVCjqj0WD1BiqabHYma7@B0vm4ZammIMIr@VrmfkGFLJFB7ZtoRlpKGQfZx2nSr1gwCoLS2upFrPDFefqifnF30Y5d3IfjmDpalitNqBTkF@knu5YxgOEyer5SSkj1aPQ8C4NksxJOh5cjkUJCg4zkaPS7QjQmc2pHwgpI7cjFRRiIKuhz3upZhG8Yz0SjHqmgHDgwg04YCSfvCpB/M1qPxsKQNhqOg4lRCYeBMi0kgk2VRs6cINDB0WtOmI1YLEBsaFhX@J0R@xCWBAOLJ98G/t04njR7@1cgXVnL1lAVSVhcGwFvapkHtunhaVwltksaqw7DLdQARtu2ZxmhNa4PSH8m5dbwZ0TmIEJQGI49KFfVCRhE3FGHYCBAvx@5ihCO36gLbYDBaWhK8oxUkyCDjoNmr5Kcqw0d8mEl2bLHPAB6DzhNTW5Bx55EdxFkF4AQ@DyVmh8TLc8gnlaVyKr5Wh1hYGnJOtKvrZLWPlDtHpIXNCs0JawOUBVVdtANFKLaLmvBmN8FSitD1eE6PPDRMSbZke1IFLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5c4B0HButMDeUUBzwFhuPLIt/Vq1DB2JnNwC1MDwZWyDKeTzyAtsVKvtZjYfpu885ECxmWDJR1s/1mnituwWS@mGZnQNtgwAyJrJJGfsXR2nSkDnc8C8ZLZ6SwSqdQ19NMWDCg73NuqIUj7rad8yQqYIPnkJsobNr/QY4IE6H@9@3IIRQsql01B@15emj1dJH5bpOmJgi40BxJSthnyDLflRMXujiQkl5A9uRQI/GQrvmNyul2FAhVKJHn5LSf2dnIdAP3ej2q5rXt23SEPCqQy/lTFRe1AGoZ@K6vBuAzUMTQVjqEuKCaQzDT5uXxRcF6kJueUZTolO33Dk1Ltkz2b4E0B9IaGyoJ0KL4ZTiQT@BimKZaos1VauUyilBGaQyie9gRJQWj2DBS9Ad/EDBUGE9kAJT0AlFIvUPC@ZmJwOOMYA9MW2oql91dmliTRNR6VoPOC7sTgfOEZwqCpOQFgyY8GNk11jKa53OfzWEIc6O6DQk@0fbG41DmsnO5VgamBbKU1tQt9oK40@qLSaYgfZ9CfEjhRAJtLfXmlHhuFUOCNcaeyrnxCmcZPvbTb2dtePakcfeCEIja32B5qMRSktTQFg8mOKdvurb4axYxl9T9e3RUMsZZH0ysRqAhq@InYFYwdiLcEXnsfwPq4PJFuBbqvFEgb3eoECcBUBcc2ARsduLIaQtIbgBQrIAqHEdYSk1XQDixjorSBMzK2P0c2LfziRwHwnpe8Rua0PbNNXsztJovBrp9NBfcALzlDwVQI7kTYOzlIwX4GYnPsXZJmJmgvs4VshfHzlYi6@mai5wB6@HMeHKx7z0U3FzAP1kOUJGa6QzMU1FTEH0MO0Spj8qyrjuALFPbSkIvKaG/1gIg93kXDjsssYFS3CiCAXMMO5o8@XROwGzr6OeSQjTcRiFF9IYYk2mD1rCIL88gWXWCAI9EPbbCedoTNGkfWjSIA2wxdYvHjOCJLWkBvQK8eldUN8USyhgQCT8uPEOS@xMZXUUMfBHjhv14zWABEw8HVpN8Qf5SXiTeiu5Pg7RYa3oGWYI19fvstw4vdVIU58vSvLyU1yCPUuayKSU9t0V3Mm4ni35Cs4jUs@DdgQCzjYLlwQnsCgvmeAKran2rSu6peMAc9kuAgEXbtnQsEPjmMy4/lHlrieP3Ea9CMimQ1i9cpAc3vsaqSTUg6xeCj6V9psyg5orfQzATpTqNkYPlb0mx36mQNQEnNyMCziIhNS5RWuK@C0oQE2hHJDYDS7QMiAWqoup47ogfMM88ozOWMyUZim0hmAep0C8w/dXwFLFAsE2Wk21YdAgS5YdPc5t5JHAzBxMsmVpOTaUzhDCTYVn@442T0gQOi/vZlpNjbRFM7AciCVeP6nn7WhSWYbrCePyMjwHA2gJHFL58H2E0nRQz/z25pgLgeaKhNhyPU1lC0ZVzZkzXPMR406DUskerLVR11eNDewK/5Af3uE83jJLUUbtBX3OT@TEiMiT07nMV3ts9YcaIKdmnnkmZH1phlym8jAbSxVoUQWNjZvBmXIrQ2fMgvC6KGM5kwQsvGKnNMbOAP@i4twX2tG1cTvQ0SYgE3n5KakpAxbbqrKI81uyVeDtpEwr7pUaSxafg7suP5NnM9KdDT5ijsb6JxPAF5FS@12Fct9PgR20wOzgeyd1A09HuEMV7VipCzLj@G0NP77EIi7DcZzPEwnVaOfJzS0x1DEIi3oJEhaXGlP@MikThFWk5sjtPt6385ZmCHprCBnKq1YLJ3FQdZbVhmv6Zvmw@lxZKb0xeL81HyNn5Nkns2S4mv7CT7nRXUWq/1f6eQwdKl9WUtk2j7ng1LcnU8du@aA0iRAoqXJNjCTI5pDuYbmo5/HGBxHoxay1dj1CHuPi@Ourj20UCN6qejJLUNTbezO2kNSc3pue5wn7rKgn3FS9M0Stk1qsN1LeK75ksBoObhK8gCjPUGy8QUKXALycU7SeIhoLeMGvw8qFz3jWuG/8we327mleoKMSmjEEmprrgBtt77GqbjSTj/z6Xg1t1xOS5sbLtYDJk2Bp/KyrWqGDTY5/j5GCtCubZv/zudiP9VUWU/QtLXfPT@ZKJTJkmKa7oG2lLWuoeUL3ZQMPw82@MDqoOQXz6dKPE9iSdLXJZarBxm6JJ4PivqrlHX1NU6guW0L18B8zkfG2XliS6ydPFxBsB9wYXt@5bbTBUqZTPEJkocawGr1buSR@/wJo8lD1HVHE3NEejWoeZigWACHY3Fd@6fktvJ4bu2niaQZtKtfq4Svca80BQYv@p1pUpZJS9@YQkqnny6gOtpAGShz5dNB81LBrY2PWBtPL1RaVGNJTCWmgHg4kehB3Qqr8UmlxnEbfY8KGFlToZN/VbuZK@9M0MVNNLQPwXGIjtmEXX1gTjTuhLWmHz1OuZ7p9myjPVFIjPlWiVT4ug41oa7bCn0fUu23@gbYxkYf1Ab9Ce0vkNKsB/@dQEwhY0VjYnJkbvbeQjnosqB6QIuqV3YC58WfJnQyDxn0BFwspnRVV5wR/j5E6XlCtGkY2re0DMjStkpbmLUEblr9WgvNqDlizwQbT13YOA3S7Dw0acHHGWFcAvXQbnYesZT9U1GPWIMz0@qPjFa@Sfav2ZcwUtOskG21XPdDDEmTH1KykFx9lB25Fmo0FU3mj2F@5TF8xWT2UXye1iHUW1qUwYUcvnQzXlULTYkecwTEUttgm/SUvkLeR5R6uX05sN3Hg0BDA79zopMpWoh4IJ2pQl/X8XdimcinDTmGDtaUI1tdBc0RDVdGRehD8tVd35hL3N2@3FX4CYfHRMd4VgI303EjbuycPz9R4vtbWpCML/8/zgrQca6Uke0@5yJ8M2pBew76X59Vm@rjLZz9/GqnTqbmLut8Rd3Te0ZP7yk9izqH53uoewBHOvxsymOVgPL3ZPsKdw@SPBpbcz3bT13N0LSnUBflIZeOhjF/YnYLd/63Iek34R3JTYgQj6/O2MGQTUSisfuhvtNTBjAy2YZjmEqCfA@BajjZw3/nzzXvHoRtdqYqVptvfQB1HLJWm5rCblQowqXtX3eeP5HU1AwZN6g@orwDZdznU6amWob11XmPrmw4pkmPhqkNbPqhGd0EndOYV91tKulTmEF1@K4TzrJK12i2eurXitRUZEdXr1LuHA73PmqXCmFMNVdZYhODk5oKtLJGSWSCij/@GB@7D41/viWcubXfGFjW6OuCYXLF35tq5SsE6Hgof7E4OyeahnzcVuVuH3pkmUKs5T7ITaRAo7KcUNKglUgPzgBN7CAT0osWFR9QeqbqTYXxraN9y9Sl2AxAk3iqb0MDhM@bvHhIEO4I@QZWYWRn0LWjX2fcXht0KvyZi7DWxcNafCXJ1owb30QzdH1ZF4@5o7K36vjYEkju0TWQZEqsdSaUwYOzW5pq2vyXJTqZuVhmF@9noUbzLV3RPG2lw5cp0PU1za5vWLiNHlSIRMtS7BbOeKP05VKRixzd6IIUTmhsDOzCzq3C7H6BebrJ5AiXeL@vdGXcVren4g47zZ4d9ADz9NaBpyB@O5Bt9e3AcJS5OKe3EDwF5Ru5q7Z2JlrBRehSV@zB4o@JToBBsw1x01Nt2s3sOuZ3HM5mtBo/Gzk9qe6dqnt8IsSnF4lNpSyxy9zNp54Dp/UxXp6b16TWKRbiHxR0qkMTpuI5t57zt1s8NotwM@ibA1s85ufex7MJ/pnj/hWF2zcqSMHEZxC6rCdrzvzZZd/kKehTYiQcOx/Ssj@qmtFlHwtpBuoXCDhUuh9grHUYlw9lB3qAPodZKf8nrlvi3ESCKzX2Z2AEJcsSqq46j8/DOI4MdpD7xApxVQvP3qT28Df54lsxJE7mU2XvUYkPQ/qopYFl8zWoww9fgVA2vj60fGXZBYZKQx84CTyv@NgQkX90iCixYSHv4wEWebv15jTqskK31@J7Gb@iidkKWHQDWxuNXQ8u9s/hMBXPaT8sZGdTuKbBptKRB5pzhCt6T0lXM00NZzZApm8a80yYwxEMMd9kB8EoMehvKi1cCXxSGfaNN6CewbhlglTtHym4dD8lSB5OjEn3jJasAc3aT8rumNDPQPIdQUd02NU7FmXHxW5eCFMtcSbTTroHn0O085kOSbmHZlgIj24NUP1yDCvJCC4SkWOxaDTAE@ESVlcHMBeKjp7isTR@qtVmwOUOwaoddn7Olu6GpXRJumcVFiwFWb3OseKHDkltDU06N3rEk58vyfXKUjiRCC@FL/QSS4c9cEUDQT4XXJ6A7aj04OUdk4DpMt/fjm63xmV@7M7u0ZFWMFraYPyc6jQniYYUPzzGTyae4B6Zv/6Ltjjp21Wgsn0VlCkgCB50N/pKz7h5zvMVuQOLynhSGHHAuKvxc2uJjRqDAQGsJH7A17hhp9snBXFsUJyqB88h16K9UvDGxXk63PTv8MbjpfE2cIuMvVRupUD8DPo62KVtp2cn2bFK@/kH1nj7LLgQTHcsNM7bcbbL2gpuTaBjGjQfpRnGFZ23wpL89V/ww5J0WENsonezp0PSvhzxTIZEJxRbLWMApXaR3CqWIUAiSGQYhQc408tQMFN4FI8w0ClO4MiEe4aRsuEHGTdqxyyxxcJ4YQAejSqrnchS7ejlu/N0vfID66eU//SzVPROEC74XaKYt4Nx5oKU75Gx/NE5iB7HhllwaRjkGXonWVQhVm54ewCJZM5keJjF5THDMEWvoXPodOza40ZxH0oE3dTO7mHGPh1hJ4ZVbugwI@3z1lGo4Nlw3YYOBt4ooea9rrIUGfAJycSxw3KQIR4IlcHFD73T2Q48mIdJlobsC@shkyVaeN4AfJyQGp4F7VfW3c1qWf@WwtSm0hzQNprrTDKTrVB1lhqVtSq5LKVt4Jns8@8vhpl04mK4ulVP2S5RLy6G36Uz74HqhgWpnqWw523tb94tJavpL19secSCwftwmW@BBDGxdHe4e7h1fFI7OT2GVrh3xc@2YfXlsaxBLqITBD1Do9PuQBdLVexvkD@eD8AjEbYkszW8xyUaDfi3sBOooHUwEVziTp9omkj9leTz0tuKL34WQMi0jspcjtqF4QzbEJgNqYaVH5h4Zp@JtOLcMXGZijIeO5BHGNxoOkeWEqmCrALESgCxnkgq9nBln/Owp1Dsq1geJ9vzuSBIMS@/cy@eV3EuCe5/J/U2YaD87evNsTxeb4J5pN4A6oW6abZru3unR1uTyYDH6ElSt1LMibMbXDhjT@Nzme5BazpAJxLiZG4lyIKUgHvFYEaX9DQV50aBagnh2OrzxMShVP5gYMyYQJkK3nRUL3NaRCJUAtRBylitqaMlHXXoK6I7RvvQ3fEqekJgO@ihdgueDArMIbp1JokftxqIVZDL7XqHJMSFvA7bfvUn7vY4rBqO0WAnUqoHhipv1LEZ/PtGJdeVqbMhE8OZVGcJloGvpuhdqLALGy3zMYotcUIEl3jZg1558cYTKFP7UqY5FdrlKE7PwCitySZeryCg9w1HKbHPA4MOAbrCxNMvbtBil/nlPtS0LRlrQ4cLdQevSnDHLcK3u31cQe2Mq2Yk3/08N9BxoAIg31U7YA5YeCtSh2Q9v7SDk9wQ90O4QyVNstviPLinJdjsWrVpEh4boYM6jgaSEmsjKo73XNHxT1bTbNBJ2jB881uhSDlJ0lZ8vh8/obNgCHgy6amMcRYMIKxdmb0vAIbSmxYMq5944iWCI8y2D2d4bTGRAMp1Vd29l6mEawU0iVpijjXAHS3V8EwStwglciV6Tl/zAc65OeVCSf34T/@U35Zy4YD7F8I9TK@D7w@ErwPuf@LGSBL4/pnny4DvD7nv@xQ22ewVESJ7YUI@eG4B@PJFcKZOKBPcy6moLl5rY0u/2z1kNi1oYFv25aGvmVDCIM@pOtBL7QNTXFMbIzjPYdyEYzyR83fAIsBXwB@o3qBGQ/kpVj2CFwWUUiksOM66JGmzuzLkqxl0b8DnAd6XA0pYKp/Lr0gpKGTi2kVIh3e7uN2aI4xGSyATA9eqWfnUbOEpGha0wdxTKvky543Ukvx9NvjJK@gSwAa4oXDOIA0evPFSQFxVJIssyTEpiklxIAtLYZRpbYOzGmiDEXIASBSDdfeMIqibhiAV8LGuDB3SmEauAdTEe9FwFlbhtya5iBKAiOPGW12mu@N4AzUeOPF10KS/GYJnCHaMYKXgPGY9/55dOBd6Xdzuw4DxfjWHdXVw/@M5V/5wzsLjzLN3zUSmb4rB2rAXx7qBG@23obQskkllsikpH/VxaFCggvJiV/8CKKFzg7BoKeqlYdq1ja3dVweHxzN3phBkeBoszMLVtdhFIhk/r3uOsFfuSaKub6eO36xvu6T0l2q8FwUhxhtSpos5L7fpkj6Q@xnfuT6bN0XMZCSln4qYVn8T27Rfaxb7ODblA9zgG2dnco1E7@7P62vVCz00k/2XefdIhZLLyFzgurDpFqnwdDGxiLvufvwTvJ/STroHszLB8S1p3nEy7h8HP3zriXfb5fjqE3fnf4CODo@PFycfOBMAdU@meFZ07wcvmFtekDVuUSUs6jjDVmBmP5G/NEzUZfZiTnE2ziPSAZ9Dcq9VtDmkTcKZzzLR/UMezTy4Excjdv3xZSTiFo4elE5Tm4EbcWDcPVnoHRZP2qamOpFoQBcQ02cMZyHtR@/08MDkyvmQeYflbNQZh0majY7QlVk39QC/EoW5N5fE6PKTwwHQ7dAw2XgWbVNxXUegU7HNAZ@dVNirQR/gOvQ4UnC0UEDLSkBioGfYLco5XvchKJHst3ORYTTZU4ZttQsjTiQaB9H0nSSNr02R8d4P0Kua82qA01JmT4Y6YNNk1/DWkWF0rUjecQX5vCi7mR@s1wOADJM2oyU@cxE@1d0brrDhSywc9yjTjMbDScYtKXF5Fe2JoImoJNvo4Q5SmvrodFRS2fyXEfDBvKNa/STWCoYZzkIvcf@4n2u@6QYbH2Xkczmp6m1lGMHLAkp1pBOEh2/OrsPR4AyL0zU64tKU9vR9Oq4slB0hlMZ30UzJu2LRk3OToqFYxAsH8NglGCWQ47Fj7YETVIRIpy@bLDKgC4lslmTkjVxE9LjtWFGWqOJwfcN0FovRnAY8KAJsFgTtkEulmx8ieH9fJFWBRsJQW2/j41Y12bmUTNbBTZlE2RLOZ26ANoUzgdEA2KiQpERoQb@AvxKWiN@2mhS3ri5RtgG6EwSg5kaTnMKFB5AvQAuqNas@892lMBYwnKrFYkm0xqS0LzLgi7U5AhHQzpHiro0A9BXn5oBqKKMBasNS2irIyxevFV1XgEDAM328XFYeAJNZ0bh773F8fC8h5RDiRdwRB/GgoJP3FW6F7zScz19KlWlqrHwPas2nC9RrOkKzGaX@21QyVb6LLGmVUQp0zWg1stSrSLHsciy2pC9HlnTUtp49wxm1@yVQ5hpJMFCHAJRY0qJl4GdQ/ipLenlJXosstSuZZUoBXjCR7yDBD3Yqebck36eWnoGyFIcQiwudyJJNVwmlk0npHsqHPWQpFQeeucM7ceg2Y8x@SY3FsAzJpQYW4IfUxXGMhs2L4xRN3pWFLZDq9kV3m1LFvJaYuYWZE1AEl7wBK4cDlthU2XCBx7cVZufFPaD@8Yxf49ZzRjtmFNtvfAUnY54uWIScRpkrhEyE3@UEBBxGgIjojcvRKAiT3/wmJOUZCz7PZyNG7HkuXY6FcxKY6WBfh16AHp5aDlrBu4vNxDVTOpn858S53El@rh9eHR6@j15EWJGFQxsHQWkl@D1eOP20zyrLPPBhP/0TCi2nAqHUsvRsNZX69OkTWBzwOa8mqyA@@Cd6ngjXzyOrjFVXV5fj@cJy/EW44StWNJLJRI@ZqqbYhWra7TZ8jR5dPR4J8c/z55QXmP/wz3iYyF84XA@CiNDQN8Jdy7kQu1iV5eXYSuaFXk5m0pm//neL9/G7w8baX/9eP6Us4uMAH7@4f4PuYyn33eLid@vrKytxICR3H348/FCr1VY247nD89zzlUR6ce0//h@Li5nMWia1WLdtqR4@v3ofzKRXgsm//vPw4eHbhm0DIYr4yTIJnPhbgK/Ecjl2xW7hc9Vh@E/u27bPLaO72bnF@5vAXqmQsAmHc9nw8ffh@c22yKTq89X//EcHn0NOqJpJnVnwdEKfQ/lCiDvBAb6s67sOVUNrCJa/D41SlUoFnKv/@X@F9NVXgAdjRmvwU825uPKjUDVRoSRfQtU8OKRMBvL9v372s0CoOgzdhiRJCo3or4Fu@BSeSc8YOlLB1ULQMF7g5ej4Gfo@41qkJClz4banr7mxab3gHuCGdmWGL8xrd4@rmOAGcjwVrgo/W/j5m//9b/7kb/6I/v6Evv8B79zOL774tMmYAiMwfkqlFzPtsDflP0om4JP0ekcIvQlRs1ChEm/wUnksHPI5pujg/TJBEs//jXCBkHtxLMqh@kRjXISkwsrBi@GTP2xcaJe2oTFJvczZdJjbGJ6HubKAfQtcIPRDpXLk4N@bJv4d2vjHhj/lg@zwHD6L8Ef/8PG8@LtIISKYQGY/i7@F9A2EzkPn9fqOjn@fe/Rn4V/zM/7t3eLfZwf/Tlr4d/QZ/05u8Y/N1CYQWltbC8ViR6AyCqZ9yucUvslkQ/g85g0FQr/TD1s5yB@8CECfqMcS9/fnye@HsXJZ/IMyVfZ8@OEuKFb9PpFY@74ai51T8c6ropxriXoVysqLTD/frwHi2Nr52lqyUa1WE/Xvq@drk4lEuhcvYthRX0DCav38PBC6w7aoBELL@GzZgVAmGEyR5wvKdBiki4EQ6rdFruYWeQC9LwJ9gdCnu0@R2PPY87SWvk5LV9LVG@Ng/H9wMIQIdZi@NKx0L92T2iAkWVo5TY/So2G6bxxIbXAq8Jfug1NNd4bpblpP65I0Gk6gevi/f2A4bw4MwGZASmeYdhBxugPP7sHBG8DXgbwv4U9Np9NDKOQwfQ3/aQ1FNl1FR8/vG9E7@Hy6/3RxfxE4Z8FPCmgGSSmcTIeT@XBYrefy5udgPNy4OA/Xy6GUfXGR4joTy6yU6S7C@/tGY2t/s9FIIRetLcVexBIv4FOpxtbE43moWn5@UUpg63HuSzZCqbXnF9VsAt35GDRRBsLWUrFv/IxRwrO6eBEAM/DsDL9nN9c33EUOcl1g@FmDR8M3RUHkpSD4XN@k5iOYcDBQQP@e/tsH/2X9vzllkfN6lLHI3f1ahD5R/ItG7@7v7sVvNRqJCE9kDf4wAPyY5O6@ik4CugPXeSRaj97f8zD4jUTXOMIq5rFWpcRjQOivIZ7rRbjMGBhMEbHWdnExTKej5SaEeLPu8hdatomWaUPLUhOX2sBIkJajBJJbKZdXhHu1UC4XhFvK58vlZQ8qDR7hBCDFlltl5PRyyIxiGTj/R9I410I3voYjbaWDV/8/N00w@KRi@ssXL6jRaKtWo4Hh2S9fLqArhXE/S6WYg5B04csX6IjhKBiD@4ZYSS2CaSelMmP0PdmWHceKgLkfvwjjhjz7IhzF@Ew6jcCYnuXW1vIr1Wp@Bdz5QjRaDi7xzTCRbqwoRe@XUkFeDTDTwiERJRVWoxR6H8Z4Flpjz6vA4TZ@2N19iKjNVnLRSHOkRL0AqVjkIWwlHynEiuKvshhlqeoyE3/n59nYyvLq8ot6fTx6oZgo38kV6b5yJ5dw6uC@3BLXreL2V/nZs2wRyFJIly8CjcZm7aTWwPdW4LI0iGGGgSRwArjkaFrhc5rnyRXr51iR@kU4XCq/4O1ayLFQuCzgEmEQXaxQpPqGwJhUO7jvfQhYEW8gVJKWM9nFVG74XX4rDUbQMn7Oz88LmUJsGeTacrFYr9cpdI1SnPeHnTpduVVJnEv5XD2BqsvlsLMcMpm0mg0tB0zaXLSaZm1cn7VwzmwRAqFJWROX0m1F09zbbW8MS2vfqG1lMRA63KttbJ3EM2uAMrNd24hnjk/XQxJ6c2M/RWfRf7RV2zw4hQSHe1u1462Xu@@2Tg8hHO/ChE//UFYGSkO5GQxu0N9Q6LOh2vLlpWyaDRM@w86Pv/r5j7/67378sz/88c9@/uOf/cmvf/knP4fvX8D3D/nzD/9tMYe/v/7lP/uff/zXfwaB/wG@/x6@/@7Xv/wXP@Nf8v8VfP9PX9hfia8Pjn8DgOsPfv3LP/rzX//yn/xL@P4r8f2X098f//h/4///Ufyh889@/OO/wh/h@fkf/vj7f/Tj7//ej7//ix9//x9CE/3dX/4K///oL//u3/8K//@Xf/N3f/k//N0f/E/k@FPu@L//1b/lv3/7ez//29//53/7e7984Pfnj/7@8gnhv/x7CHl6OZ@C5yn1@taQX/6k8vw21BjnAjwAXPePf/wX/wj49o@5778HH/x7Ub/wPF5MjOy5RGwc@AvGvqRAb0q/@OKBAsr/EUMhmH2ZxEahaTf017/853@OwROw/8iPIS3Nwi4hsJfbLwD2X3sF88P@4sdf/ezHP/@HP/7qT3/81R@gJEusFOO1eEL6ypQQAOaeAIeA@afAAaC0hqvji2wxkAHH4hpOYQSk2KdPQNJFcFUYWw7ksuAL1etV/Fycp6oXqYsq/9TBn0xVMSSZukhhfDKFmrtUpZRQhBjIawnsnmU@4RDDeQb4DgMrRfDhFEQMhpkYj4pB1HqMVSqVWGBYgTgCBS@mGbJqAY0rtC0qgBcT8TTxRgE0VzZcJyyQshI7Yo3lypAnjGFAlTAwLBAGHQWlTDBWqGxChpXhJkNciDwW@ATPT5VqoTKsIrofqAiAI7YOWQJUBUs3rP4A/grhBPjAcPMHKEqhEotVCxBSoapSbvEG5SnlqHJU9xijemM4GLrweP6Cse@CUiHIbTwgPBPQ@BsbQz@nqY7nEH8RWxbVoX/XSd9lTA@tOiT68DAe/xyDKb0AALyJBO67gm8igaV5AdFDjipG2cIjxjEA5WJiqsgLoEE@FohR@8bIA/lDGZ72Wav6PIgOq7O0tASutWowGzwAc4FZVyXbkS1cliA9qMSC@WIQg3Ebi7J0SAbF8uYy/Erwv7VIW1E5OZYDS2Ec88PMzSMRyxorRohK71aN6rJMJY8RXCA0Duc6LK0tgfK5wqKBCN3rHiWrVDFNeL6xu@vGEPTMeDAYl/J89jiKRitEfjBKpcoP0spqAJ7kH@CV8uJyc2gGfM1YEvsiErR6l1ijfglO0EvygWpVrI8xKVA93jqBBCcHTMqkkwyU07uV1cxKbiWXyebzudWMtJIvruRzhSzIs3w6l8lIxZWVYqG4ek9FegFyIV5abubWqv9g5vPf/IN5n/mh@AlU37NhkiXuA9VhIpHKUIkrUm61PKpAOSgoUCWNi6vho7sEbosMXNA2rDvc8QPFCtwlkE0X4MMCCwG2AEHwAbS4MsDEcvXuQVms2@HLOvjaXVDKASNEAxfACBxbwJz4BLDVnoGoeSZxZy4/dqbReYJHx/YhA2gDne3hBknHYCcG34i3rrQCa@LQUzUQoFWOc6BoPYBX4Z/XA2spL3Y@po0ef4HdhmWAEvvTYdZl/YpHbar8uIsXtSPjfVR2X3V6D0Ccmn08iKNYf28YtvpNKCDOZnKAdfixNMOYB7DKTg8fqOUb7ygqLhfSWVQAP9p9uXPie55s1TZ2Anm2frC/OfXICaAc29vaPvG8qzzWTZrzUHzY2tub9ooHGiKLLLcaj4NwhB98xulDz@TS9y6IlHzkFnYYmVJrbAktzRx0d3wf6kWlKg87@gCYG8yohlJZP5fKoXq1ABJmZTW3mk8XV6Gr7g/6bICEYKeDAusOnNHuAYoa3ChWlPiBB9UO7IDJ0scb7fE2BCdgKW0wX250OsvRxPdSDUz2YCA8MAidltrtQQFuDBcg0JRlBt9v/UB6xf9xHg9weB4UNhOjzQHHpTG1w9KBJE1tZYqFXKGYzRTihWJhJQeWXS4uZeLSamG1mI5Laakg5Qu5ohQvrBSzKyAMITZXXA2EQGionVQKZL0UDNJT1Vt46@waXt9rJHvVQIhPDMAAiy9cDMleADRIMFu4SEO6YAA3wTK1shjEV5qm8YWhgFBmLRba3t5Ib28Hg@vowZm8jXQw2EZPrpBOr64HgwrFbIC8zgSDBk8DUQDmcE86vb4RDA44Ajw4Gwz20LOVRzU0GFTRs1Hb3sZ8LtGTwfQAdsVjuEdzPasApqMnmyU9Nhj87KEDuBrPaIVKuoUezBNjtnnMBsQFgy/d8qTTgOGIw3EMO25da7VgcJd7ajWMeUUVz/GivkZPjT7BoAUe4MFgsAuOrgW2djDYBCdyYjDYAldrJEMY3vCLZyx1Rw4GR5xASKJgcEjQcusqCFqUCMdsdnZ25J7TVrr8M7L4swVFgxh1ONjabr582ex2m9aotvXyCGNevdqRL0cDq9ltimTNBnwMSAMxV/3R9AfKuNtoyNrcmNcQo0/FNEYNBcvWkD9DmcSni5n0G68g5hXEzFsa4djg0wfQJn7W@/Bcl5sU434ohp7DZjNYRh51RqaCEyjYZWgzUdkf0pdbllFGF6jdbDEcCcdH51I9flumGNZnLBK9S5fvEaQTobeVoFgEHedudD6spOugbEtlnNuJLPafB0HWBUuL8vPIEN35YAnU7ZVgtIRvejE6YRZOSM8HhWB@NVhahmfweTALzmEkHU4zBj/R89X68@AqIgk@f54IQlnACyAyJAyuFhFhcRWG/vI90MOBsag5cJRGIxK5UeSraJTXib8dip2dnUXv@AYqlerolDuRYXxY4aVharR8C4WfxtTGY6WDlmNYHF8XKHD7PF2iSkL2BcqepVLRNZRIKEPg@Ykmp5OslOAvRpEK@WgS91s3jE6DXlHAPrkz2GdnM65ZP2qFZ3hugs5MuhtsSCG2S4ETVB3pxYsMT6s38V1FdNwWbBJ@bQa9WUgBRbIYCFSFLrUpO3Jye6Bj5ZL49iSnLGJOlKGT3FFwG0zLDdvgpxOTW0N8waBq6G7E8Qg0gn5y9yB5qttyRynfJc4S93TkF8854kFbtc3kShVccjtCGTE5ekNlblSrlUalr/RNZwSmB2m/VS8tjn3rjEPiiQl303ijsg5VSZd1vFZCQe/SMDQEJbMyoCIcKhaeYNg9WEo/VyzLsIJr9IbBVu/TxRb6N4A8d/eJqjkAzNlyGygBFuD63aBUgjzuy93KOWb6BX/WEsFqsJ5InH@pg4ZbSZdHIbliD5p0bQFLN0EFz5eHECatrpQ1qCg/IrJEG8Xkco81K83vh@WrCgxWSx2WYfmVcuN5o0J5p8uUvnKeSRfjGQlGKhjBIAC@q@DPwFeqLy5GtIhjbOlAjnSphFQBcpIXnnI0llnWIm2DyWsJoi70kzJhhyiNSYoUu4r1CajHTDXeiwCSI0XWeOpogmVXouUJokei5cgii1Zs5XO5U2GR76Ncg/@i4bzsYqOS5rr8kj3on6cX81L8LtFI3Guy7SxJq5nS@WDpPIEFT3/prgU/Av2AgPcBUPv908YwOJchzO00fDgfD8jjMLMMSpamALmlYqYsQAKm6LqRIIvgu774dqhIOLyaCYej4TJALUIwSYDoHXXYMIiR8DMQHqAQgPQoZiDeUpwBKJ8g1mZKwO2VvBQI3Qfaqm2ylWIgdBe4v7tfq7q63Ws2GsmxhOt9xlg3BpZripa5ko0QWyRXIll9wWqVWveoVhagtQ2yL1MBdsEP2SVSi9@6mBZbq37Pnxe4jArZBDhxaLU5tRarpi4CwWAwFHRXQSKFXJTbtT@E6LZNtnHXQSEAXbr0Bmkll47pEvzzevSHfVW7K2QTVbJ5gCvu70MxqBvuo6imiFKtA9q@EAjphnDixLgDEgTEYy4XRPNXYeZx8fvV7wvfvzk9OD3YZi/SpUKpwMlwwS3SuBSWwmDuvgC9TD3aCoTML0ZO@kF/VQ6VzHB2JZydUKkvKuJ8eQSZIHKOy0bwrZ@DYVuPgqtSkZ5LqyXVFqs6kZI9MBUr@lzKZ0qZtBQN2fd4@DWzGqKnlF8N1UMc5cpqFNy0HpGRQtWUCJZWMVWC@4B7cyG7@CWUSRcCocKbT18Yc99OrGbIlUqJwi7dr93Df/X@HAz6e7Lr7@kff1Lwc88B6B8TuB56jD8TcGOYcXz9h8Qa/1@jn40DXvJgHhoi9Am6u21/3/i@EQqEimEwScIskxNlHApjGbXrZZ3@FHsZ/74fByzbtr3s@cC7DHVmuarEQB9PpS6ibzOgiReL@UI@FPjN7Ce1DJb98kKNhfmFVnwcw@ssvQNW4Yn3heFkzPJCYvP4YOP11gkOZIqO73tlGwf7SYzCV5KOT8i1NEW2tJF4J@kIoXD8O9k4ZAYYUJuHlOaMzkZSKM25iFyWdtsl8eKe@DWTkllcq8ul0ispKcekQim9WsrkmQxyyMa7EIRrCZMyqtaGYY64/RTZiFLihRrCYNyeCmasrZTYy8M9SkHXJCwvbG69OWAH@3sfkm4oDz/Z2T1mxwfbJ2e1oy2ox5utYxasHbPd4yA72z3ZOTg9YbX9Dwyij2r7J7tbx4ggFUAZhvocJ5hnzLA1e2SnUNmzyaKZCLaN1pXiTIbLlimn8H7WyWAd39ai4DsOJsMHugrmkt9YOq4tcM2JIXq53bYCeChTbbEFtJQWlmFgxjOhvbS9ynKD97dpK7fIWiv74VXWSu/r2bVVpqXFH9NW@tkjtri4eKEHvQHAXw3PVvMH4XZ@CBuXaffj1kIkv8KWwULLrETHMfsHhwtp17dwdnSyIHlxR5sLGc@zu72Q9Txb4FvxfNtnmws5z7dee72QHyfb31hY9XybWxsLBc8HTLpQHOPc31yQ0gGXWNegPC3QG@ki27t7W2wZgKLliVicCUPHVDAQIgLqEL8hg4zT5eWbnhEnVb85moJuK1@DdsEnoBZQdTpHutbjbNkw4QeUOQCGZAFP95atbisusOJdRjCyBO4CC1ihBawQwC/g2WyEY4sVlokyiF7o8G0DEX63XZwFT206gfmdzdZQia4CM8TpciQ6iQspFPFqysDCvUAZ6dBsYYe2FxMoGDQsaAWjUTy@t3@6t8czM0lRjAQJknGtcQ5OwwRsUEX4xapDKG8c3izUFkirBaFV4OszA/cTrRmYbk0kBdRzYaEFCCapey1rcYZaVRzXpBEvevixAACGaHCnwcXPLUYiLaxrV3FaVKAoEnPrYJvXEFe1K2yylaMMMyVKUTQ/cPDlC3N9F86k15r06mGOWyDnxeL4eEkrCBvFsAX3wChB0OF4SrmAHBOLQWqoDsX56rUARIcvP0vvlrIKGaXD7NkzKsca@IphygLTxShHlkAQRCAIRuRDZF7RFqm40YXUMu434e@eRyLiOMKvS22OvHtAQLJOF3SqVb1e6DXngg62Y3lKIIuoThvbGtzZTAP8KB6Bk@OsCd0kztxIKY@RaGXFmRJnHQiekqkNVQfOVayxTHRZATojtf7@Jm8hfukNhfMAqjHIvRI1GAiLZ9h9idEXFpoWWNBlFwrkIUEB3yLTRJAQHO7xdEeblGyZ9xdkS0z9lJS72yWXj3hqYAfBaURWvKeA84qoLgVWx0Az@AUy7L8VQM9ZkiOLxQSEx2UCbGsSLpHgcPcuX36lElvTtVj85lqgWH6wFltPrMZvVwsY1sYsArUAER8BvDGApp/J1szMQwFjIaGg2vw0FDCAjnkJ@vgEgiekhyF3nD7x7elhkC5Nd2Xot9CCXCrwJJPe1qS3PenF7gshMgObILPCvrAmuqQ8uPC8OiuAo81l5WTCzqSXJmEqTHHTdDwJzHMAnkNRycGQAWeFMUqQpI2vdpD7@IKhCqttN3b3t04mYxFf0m6IgvccQ9coj@gkmCgQxtsR9ES9EkU6SASub0YOeR5xomfj@ORoq/YmDuWLsrVxD5jWAeBH9ISJGty7OUCorrRgPG7HWeS4xpaj7BmWLM7EZAF6npyFZtgKoHowx/bAzFBWaQ7i@Sd7Ugh7ZGBOVsEIi0TZl4sLGFLTq0zqm1@y/ay@mm2zUXYVlV2Ox9NBhJR3Bcw@75pc2UDINr/HrzQ3s8t0mq1YWeYoPdC4h2lrFj/V6x7HNhoW3VO1pkFGmV1meIgZZYu4gwTGxUnV5nEtksZG5AMMxW4MYTic0wRcjPRzZE@KdRUsXpa28q1l@ZpGO1mWBC/LGmU6W4bfiMlOMJcCUyen6SoXw3RMGQ8Xi8gDmiI9xCArEODzLL4bvSIGvtTFiZboJhaUKY0GXuDZaERsRevg@@MHVguGfFSXbQGGH4xN8kjqSOiYjBTkQf1pMqKt4mFgvB4RRp0phPQa@wrdHxihHAMBr2S2o5hUKl8xcJ4M33bszxAM7Ak/NCse0vOVOFoSWvG2jP3BRXY@cQkTxzGwe/E5wSCeZ0M9Np0T57HNnDi8a29eEvfw@Jy4y0F/XglAMDwQI45/zonRjYN5CfgdRuOI@rmPgOd@Atfrkej8pod@NdnivkuoiP4n1kARNyrtHvhYEJRLwYG@tg5tKsC0LRWvyp9G5B1Ah5SRYdR3Ft5jq@iYk2S7parT6F1MAhEd5qTb4Nmw1OoB1u@kTCEa9yH0YWzz60Ifwsl8SKGEc5CE2DHxvjsDanuokQWn8Y7TJ/EqB70N5t04gWE@Ao@xY1hsfBd4AW/h8mI8Zp7T5cboSrOMQ@E46Y7NL03cV/YQtFsJKeon6G@bfeJbs0/48sc@@ZOyrrDzyXLUYz5/CQLGdXQ7@E/KyC31ZG7Rb6qxn2sU5eoB9sV7ZXzZ8PskJrP10AgJ5PGUWxVCjwFPFBKIy4/oG@QLNZ847T4v9Xj8Wa6whOSl4RJv3Btoct1X@ADehNFo4BWyjQbdHdho4MxSoxHkOdDAiwOef9AVnY3HJUFLbRgUGwkm5GA8mEjUjjd2dxOqHozz28crQdsxLKWBV4AF47jsWwmSwGogTE/RzEpQbMCTbUapgw/nUfPlARX8eiYExHPZ1SmT8d2wX8@u5a@S8YQqGVOZje@rfEJuR5QbHs1/LCeLX/zmZrRBd5PhZW@WoqKg4feqi1eF4yUeE3dH4JS@KALP16aZPhtv7OBFokcDw0Rb49UX9EL2CqPZvqB7l01w5uoZ0dtxqgcRjDmVc1/wkN6@xOhes7Yi9CyaHkoGx3daioIlRU19/O4qaPwqkPGANnm/jShv3J2btHEac6qoY8FimFj58yBefwMNcGiY8OtdgQNu7xIccOM1OBjkijpw4x04mKIjHOI6HHDRhTjwBPYOju/f7MtDtT/AiRv/JQtCkxsXC4d8rAmN@hQ5Kf04RREiqeFFxhGBNxoLloJQdZsu35m@gAfh593BE60HZoUs3RiNxfSpDvOQzr3VJxr/HTSSTxFD0WyL0kDaeJAFuRJCaaVSHYxPH@@4IgbV56kwg896IiKoSdxLPx6vfHf4VCbMC6QIGA@8MOMEfJbJ/5ZDUu6jJU8FGbeYH4orbnPKjVtoHyy4H4OrqEUDj1hS/7@xk/xN8l@oqfT/vVE0Y/r8PZsyj5gw32yt/A7Ngv@q0P9Xhf4nKPS/M23@AZV8GuVsj59S17@qhn@7@kUybwTDhtW9xqm3zE/Rw35HisDqN@kBbqnPpcd0ga@Pzy6ajH9Y/4mjdOA3qZN2/mzbqNVqJ33JOnpZ69Z6tSO8Lmk9vRc7u1xZ37xZf7nerm1udl91N/aVt4Xayp75@n3hw8vO7WcFtPedg1cfbzWz1Qu8PzJvzpTDm6xSsGuDwefdnZGzs37a3zjOfVi9SW9puc668nlTszffnLx/ffIydxy7@fzq8NVtP923DztpudjP7rzJv9sYnemB3LV62t7eUw/6x@2t00x/b1P9sB3bSO8dF99K6b2tm4/ZjZtYLp3aNV8fvDw6vWxufdSOdvc@tDc@G3L@89WNuZtqFzsbl0fvAgfZt9LO54OD7lam@HIndbPZMdvpzI5m5S7fHx2un37Y6b2Wt/rbudPi@8vRYb739u21sx/rrpzlB2/slZhee/s281p/eX29dRRoysaJlVXOjLeSeXNzaBT7q8rr/Z1u/60l6amD3LvYcf/kZnNrXfu8Osyefjh7e7Ny/GHw5u2rjwdp9fi4uSXnzWY7c3x5shJo9bO7sevTrdOC/LJ99rZ/vbuT@7CZetNT9mvtQ@3qZXfno3F8uLdby9oDXdrbuNY@vOxdvrna3NjVjMMrTa@tpHLaSfvDwUHg9JXa3FR23tuvape9D6nc@tXKh1jbfHlyedu7erV@fHpQyAwPR2ljwz5q7nSGm0f5TCHV0j4f3XaMN9Lp21j@@vJVRv1Qu3UC2dtRrrinfVD6@qtYq/tx@FlLxU4laePj7u2HD8c711azpp9@frd9dGm9aesH9kH66NXrN03tquBcmh/142OplX6pXL2JpeXA8HTHhjZSTuTc6kl/76053DQ@H@1@tPO3seuzq6yyeXX0rvb5KN280c33urWn9jfS7QO59s5wtgbDl63i9enVjrb3@cD@EHizJeVy20bHXu@8Wym@T72Mda5evl@Xjofpff2os5K39t@9PVPVrd7709ujVm77nVnoO3r37e1pfyu2tTfs3SqFdFM7/nClB05zx0eHmRv9tdp3tneO3uSdg/Teu8P2zkiqvVWkG311Y5TbHFr57Nnme@vD1Y5upj6onweHaeU61v5gOitv1Wan9U5t9V8Hjl/1TvcP393s5vLWy76urh8W0vt7Oxv73fbK69Hum8HWXvOy/XL3vfLePMlfZbbWz/Kb74@zzsnVa6fYuu5nDwuxE63vdE9jgVeD3mD18Mz6/G74caXWbyrZI@2DMVqV@huvzMzwXW3r4LZ7dWga@9J2ZpQ63TOutPTtyc3tjp2vjWKF4anTN5wTaZiT3gayN7em88p89fb4YP3VwcdX8oqqnsmXx@/a6expIaX2rOxuPv9S2tru9D/3i4p0u/kmK2f7vZi9d5Vqb7RP351daZf91/3LVqBQtFvrux8HsrHVzEjpD@udrZyyt753Iimn3dfHK5v76cP37cPTz8OT9sb7wem7AzW9dfmquNddeX/0rvh69eOJfSKfGe9fW/uBYSFr2FK@mLvJHhcLBz3rOHt2WXQ@vr7Mr2tnTenVbqavbKvW@8KocGXe9m66N8dKutl9uflZPupsgSQ9PUzLucHV/vA4kH130r9eNddjH65ar9/rklY4U1dTJ58vi1e93uubzdbKWe32s5x7eakUj7dTTW079zJ2tPH28LK7eXZbWGmn1/feye@HWz3nQ@Dtjrp5WTy7OhiOpLfbx6N@La1ruevjs9z1ibF@fLZzXOi9aVqd5s5lD2RDf3R6eTO43lFWe8Obwuve5Ts5vfe@sKHbK4fpwCtlt98@Onn9vhbrZJSic33wYd88K5wNc28KxlnROCior2udl8O3B52t9Kqpnp0MT7d6qfUNtV8AmXKonVobB293Pp69MtOBjJ5fv90wcqufY9fDD/mz1GFsb/ChdZLpn1nWznvV2n5/ffj@9XFtN7bbHL08vJIPPmzljvc3NuxXsW01r4x2sjd2bSOrdYyA3V8f7g8ts5j9eLXXhZHAaBfbL0@yZ7pdq3VudgvHW7XaS7u5@0oeDl92VmGMwM/W2TujEvgNvwovwG/B4w@Z37kR6NvdpjEEecmP9AXouFaAjmsF@AEt2iLNtx//JrUcOPGfVKB39PIJnkETlDXWNlB5SLJd775afF1FnPUNSK6iq2WY9ES04kBGGw0@DX5pvgoPDdIbBpWhqRkqvgkI30qANqk1fhlYMnCgs/4I7U1H6fPzEyq@zEdcL0svMuDvTKLrLQMLrRZz38OYpMtTvbcyfgIFwtS7Cbott8sSiVZHk7s2OLQ2uT4Fjr3b3DEHTZVx8gOzkPYaspTOia2p9O40LNwJvoNo/yXTDP6aBNfikEGZGNGdIzhJRfeOKPiuNlu9VrQRvfdCaScDfMfnk3ZB@sNwe/dkGF3xObU3FNQNxZraAGryhO5Ka2r5BV4H82I5JZZYURlqyFZTdfBNwA1@FqLBc3T3vJmTew/pKK9YoOWKEWo2dDluXJxLGqJvKhVSjLaZt@hECUeAqiGqqO5uw@Vlk1DSvivGPT7My@bDuNV@93eFegJ3W1Um8BpAqwHQihakZ9bsv7Npk6MHVA7wxfqt97snDfFyFL7FcOK00wM7Ln1ULrs@s8xr4Cu/KPnstkzcYQDFx2lHfrc0VPXa4LwcpH2PuD0SWhst7PFuS3rTPRYdsZm0G@V8pc53EKZp655LcC/NM84Jz3ylejYm6ILYUOHxwBPT8Q2aHGS2voi4YykKAdBuTvdoyNRmv98x7z3QMk1N1q/QVeZbZcFesFq@xqLXPvjqgVNZXl3E/kmyEbDekNTbBjsuaNDymoUAxIZYt5lPdezOtN8e0/AW9rLG@THMw7O6NM1oRcbRy@6WG163qJsTh5/K6gBnEju4s9awRjwjnJ6JlMsAgvt0SCYourtb1VfrypgaiI429fhKAXxbdoPw3gBlXM44e7y0PKtFYgfaATS/qHwzEEKde8Wq86weloVA76i/MhNJx8RxtxCBM7XMHMMEInQEx8EwRjzCd6fOUIXv9PK4iHE6nafr8M@e@z0lvnEXO5SC054oQqLYjdFCnyqcV2gErXpdB7Masx41FO7gxiZUiReZChY@hjM1FptoJx/ycxXpJrEYUTsyJxbEkFcjQXpBe4KhPXHQGnwrLuvwHVyc1oEpEq1BRl@@eB0GvB43HroHLIElvPeOI4NzzuR9WRC07PrdTui5KWZMFE@q3s/upaejpWCAGzemOlS0CAjMBr70xWQQJLYsmSZ3EIS3fQmCsbGp7EJeLS5GINU5waUKdfaMRaS1tchqIkJB3xWiUa8ziuQZX3JfYhDS1SqLZJYjWTfxCiYGlNlJBCvzEWQ4gpXliOQiyAgEUg4wcBWDkHzHCpxrJxEXfIg9vPVJGHx1zJzclzMxqb62VsA9nr7AqcSZ@UVfzsYykJijXohNxnC0PMIXXp@sESDPZnzjiA/FSiwLKHjWscmIca5TEV6m/jxX6nMHp9@Z8uKe03AHH0qOb7BUrPMC1hc5lW9KNxm4TccSgfgWMZPeJTYO4yy9jGwOOgJ1Scitp@ChqTh/l5wYtIB@5alR0Xc4giBQDBARXDxqnF0@NtY1v32wQ@AOTfDxOseZFGcFMENAooDEKEBiECFEA7XbaPVNDw6G4kKU7/jmAxhlso8rznh@ANoJ1X43JxJjnHy4wg34xLu8aAzh9I1Agsbe7jo@3m0d4Y7Z3f2X0IQLWI84G/@61VzkGL0qbsg6f7@I6qhQBJBt3KARdeVNNZk/Brr5C2wucgE/jZ0npNohBOOJhXZIfKE6DdUQ2DgpXT5SHKIjve7KAyhEy2BnsBuFyRqSY8Rf01vgb8WiQ2@UmkgFDi@hKCBSCGl2clTbP94@OHpDlDts1PYOd2qIGQzMlmy1Gb23BTuIrisaH1Q9egZw@O3iK62xTnLTfckIf9k3wvIXAHLiAWCDYhoUOl0irC9n@hl4HjwvAUkUDxqUikZbMefgxr2rHpiojD0HIW9FXmoxFIoyzRsJacCbHQldOVpFSUe0NBRbDzvA2PQeG1nn8iTl4lsHK5NeAkg9F/WoLvGLxd96ls3Qq5CRj@yBiavDSjvoJ7/caik23Wgwpj6gVLQOZSIki49QEDK/9mP5wc@meGOvwEFvgqRBN@3pvWM1d1JZBO2R0@4n6bg@BYljcXWkO1etJLVI5MzfzDyhOqqTKuNDmfHcLnlul5AbF7jsclohU@vnlxOK2DzyqC55Lrlu7GpmXD3xtpJTy3Wg09s9vGeI5kK41KEGw2aiOzaM0YSse@Y22TO3F4974nzl7nGlTBB2UiMTA854/BQGc7sNZIvMzG3QyRWyvgYWtj/36MoNemik5AedXBOD4IlTGqBOu3Cu@MQzVA9yBmICaUinZc5FdnUaVDx8EYGQJdzyRH26Bp3CFLMCqg7SYnw4TdSVVEnDFoaiLxDFqhiFrbbbyQlyPJhZ7ekDXQiEofzA4fhUAj/GxzMqoJPeIlkh1MghY52VIriumkhAgiif1yCdBsQt1oGKpzrzq1GYrYaonKuTqfwEDIo64Za4KEDQL2D3QKibeXluvX31cA/DYeKor2LpsjhB4Z7oPT1kWSmb9R3/PTjbZ/n8@HQw3lLGVjLp8ZFjvK@M5YuBnzRPNp5P4PyIHUc0KLIV8gya7qALKpoGnZg/2ioO/Vg2bhYP@WNU9pSrZW7B2kIci6HBZn18P31Twfew43qtw6ShlAwsgFCkOWDxgkt38AbA7kC2ZN1R@BlLFORiZRczpISowyoW1AtfTI/bxlDi4@vZYViwFD4BDCFto0WbJBEHpYOWHvRpN1IcFYZrxcJrAFRHHPRfIJkj2IGLhipnAjfQFQ5Vlzc4CYVIoB6NkyycjDQsI/X41ItwZUhdOdlLUylP9iQa0tx35WIBiLyCVYjG3B1YEASeGWbIHl8WLwxzu6QHPBb986YGZwcZbpy6drhAw8eYWctfrc@ZjCHuavnHoKHYxESoqE71qHsGjiSAewSq5c5DcCB6DOs0PBEubo0iBcF@aat8LpyRjCAtgkYpGlIs5DrcpSOur6PoBe9t4cTPFeh9UbEzYCQOzHnHIwUEsnyUQ4izkdMQ2D85xNCPA0rBO@pyarz/YIg4vPNuKL6JQ1wrHN1RYRcgAm7XktrFy8/PpM2vheijlCk/kjZdUoqK@vryfDBeZQGGtfOBQaFIHrmVcsFOD8fn3lxAKj1NSD1W@Incnlp4kd0M0AQlnlh0jxD3Yq5uHlJI3DeuFb5IJbbVCDXT1z5cSYJGFIxAPEv9XkxVCBq4UoGXrulLwXVmN40rSShGHPqdFTkCynMsZ9zjwK5A96Y5x@d651WUc7JbVbea1IL0xm5NNWlonKyr6Bb@uiak2cqu@irrnjKeqKxI5NZz9n4HHRwdzbjh9y/ggBIUJ5eD37Xj7Ls2LoaIEP8Y5VJjnvybPOvs65DfV8Y90qufV1Y6NOt5eF8Va4co2v38jukQb9rt5PjKZhoCJAQ39LK7uZ6nWlgQ6gwoPRPpMlEx7eyxs4ui0wF5TVv18V7avYyLacwxhKXCfuB4aAi6VawJYBfsC8l5LEDUg8XX1vthfVwkJPNEJ3W5AyNiMTGeVSZmg8cHqB9kRD8WITt9R5QfTU8yZbYUI4zjw@R8HG4SMdyP@3/ZX5DRgwVBctAakRjrvDUjfiXC/W@7MjrW3UyhuYHeZWbg57NQxIT@lku7ekDEHOsLnnXA7QG/biAUbVcZxIktUODBNuZHo@MMcn8QfnzDyGe@wIdH8yAl3QDiT0ZXTfgFEi9hxmcWmT4jZraY1DpEUZO3yWS5qSFpIsTDzqvxzDxHZKlMApcBuTMmzdRqAh2jQ840G1fml3@QKosXipOd6r/9Axt@GSuPS5ZjO8vEw8HubgdCofZNTeEnd6S9Ru1g17vaiol33Cu2gUF20rC6qRv1Sk1xwMCxuLYqoQywn@MlVTymsXUKQxleOOUk2bHCNyug3otq2ScyJ5VB9BMmwhuwdADudEDj1VsKvrTEucH9AwKBnfQXFqJlG/RwQ2cjw2iOSy@Lkzm8AHEquw2F7wJhBs0kFCDVkh1bGSkpTJhqavDTl/F26BSY5CmsYepAV/Yg9TF0CSV5KV/LgU1fwejk9FSudA1dIIFzRxTj4Cu@afcIziE49Jr7pgFt4@1PFUYCXRJp6NqI6XgFQFfGd80zeuswZIWcdwPVpB23YlGHtjwoZEespIt5Eva2GOEoHY7fySTE5aIB/nraEp7vsA1kF0uhvamUfGJPy9SeDN4xJzdRcDt/MqyFl3N9fZ@Gt8UjlfKlNfSn7PuYt8eD7v8Csj@08yOVwulRU5NHLHgj073cbGNlNZ0voa2ldnViQ@wteImOT2NXhia@5BU3BuA47qbVlGtFY1lsxneqPQDAY2cAVQqETEvu9mUXMJItMczGd0cX2dcTJ/rHUYahTYZ08NwEG1vUeDKNMWmMjU5wiVEFiSmCxbigREFqwc9z3PJsGCYrgaOtNAddGgzwXJabAk9HyfEmJpCj1Ugz@hyeJXhC0bFIy9CPsfNXvPurcD@RobJz6OZ15i5QBMsBqgV0/QovfdlNjyMHgvlWdGDA5qsaMCIss4YwRvksAUDjGBbhcDaf96TFcxekbewe4KwNZcg3F7sxWEVTXPb44J6SZebbUwIiAe@bQsakK7BSKXdmJFzD1/W6nvUwj6VZowh3j6eI@Ki37JHD3b/Q4btP1uhOMEaXeBI5o2V3V71UZvcuIO4BQQ0Hd5Ykwu7OAdQwLVybGe9IAdIHXSvsMbS@AmS/AkkNh2yG45KvGnyDd53PdgkVZDpaqrtrWBBeSZddavC3e3vtP17MesZbc4EqvkjvCr9jQp0OtvhCDK2SiAWmibLi4CV4hLiD4xJDfITzAwVMcoOYTaRJ07g3ocoLyudcQVigzpmgISXOhqyLs@/cfIqzkfDiFfQBfst0Oj6qSGXvWmpFH/Tv0BiJ8yQDM47A90wBaV8O4K@w6Cyeude7YZQgsY6CPECCAoPO3XCc2rhLx5l0X6acW/QKLy7iQY@Y5f25e7EudMRXOgdThP7rfJgofdcOxnl@uGRADsl1ZOrxcW6ciF6phyPjKjKMj0B0MDyPVBVWB7rF5Dx5R74ouqNErNMIAYPzsA0Z1x0bSLuIewMZawwrYCA1RhWcw@P3f6HCy7sFXSCD8CUGgIkEAoKFylxll@KJzCD6hrEYxoNRNxk/MEtoZbvpZ@Kx9Qg/T@/Hfz@@JI/o0BjGG6Oouy8FUjRGy0QCb3vK/Ux1qXi/RX1nyjtV3xl6ePV9gB5efWfp@ZPq680Yv6eKwBBDD7Rx0GR/DhY1QHuBfJ7iOcPA9HiE2vwwnXpg4huEplLTqyFmUxumadh4ifn8EvA85xSC4n3hkOdznkcJ3GAgp/j0kVRIQ9fD6/7tAO/iloH6YoTc@CpGPn6BPqnxuW0xRlMAYi7SjL7nTUz5IYOoGEr8Qa5I9OqHWXGZytUJUNuuaH9xhfmyKnsFp4pyG4xRYq/2Uca9Phy@qtP2RSiNmwQJFWXzkgxQ78B000kwbH4SQXUhHydTIdXZ3FRuI2JqsbvS1YRI7AR3uZU01rqDvrWmBklnYFefPuHZsd587zDmMjhvDJrpDcfcURpMsd0OzbZt8I3Y7FDMTuGxJ1DhnZ5lDLo9hhdFoQ6IsHxLecdA7R61S9Dq8f2bA7yrpuRui4uMq@/NH6fYqcnAyKfz89hz3xyyDVT8myOcS@ZzARHfMCF2WC0suLrTwnhKe4EkvQdc5xN9fMZhnD21ma8Am8gPUIQ3OBMH2R8RO83J2B3EEpKngQRlx8E781GzVnkVsPrjZCYuw4wTogbg3vFFysqCBzq/sJyNfaWl0vmLuwesMq@06bmFpGOo04VsKjjVl36kcHwWcXruBoqDuWNpNpW/h/bzcuWr12D3f4U1IVOXK@MEp4CRi5ujQdnBo3l9vIAcb9bgnAoWOKDcNyy0DUfxuZhvcD6Oepd8A7YXmcoIF0uK4vTAnr3GjUZzU9OKW0@GpqKjA4gISkCqFV87w/UyfFsbpn5D5qiXmBvANqlyeO8sL4bRwlVmN/EsJSyjpShtG1VWGXmFyhnB4w2iu7qrhG1V7qKFCJa6K3rd4tB8NFmLPbXFT2VsHGJRLOXzQLW4sY2lSUJb0r4fYIWNntK6Ilh8a9EYe0LVE0A23UkYHWZ/HsgWTjkYFouF7YCQ8XykORI7cab1KCGgyhPAxHmVWSXEB4zqJ14FOcVW7nwdTtW4Mo826@CbNsK2eM@FmDNC2vrnfnDWJMlAXnkTMjA8a@KErmoTHp/5HWedgYay2DCTGIeScLKyfh8qls3FCr/EcKKaPs8EEBesk7E@jGIbiuVhiNAwLkZiLmm@Dl6cgcasHgBOcGjPxvLR1yMakHKCbhPLO3QoaDx/AdE0fx5BfrNdmA7utbAUYUJgmnQ0TpnMoqWheBarbugJP2YONosY4BAs@tT2q/y/1H4MFSAdZQ8IGDz@jjOMLRknK6nowvqEnk61REYWVQE50B9ojqwrxsD@f9p7tuU2kuueha9oDbWLAXGnKIkiOFxKIrXLRBIVivLaBXGxuAzIkUAMjBmIwFLYinNPJZUqxxs7dmyncrGTSl6TlB1XJQ95X/@Dv8B/4JxLd0/PYIaktOt1JbVyeYnpPn36drr7nO5zGcx@3YSQu0JBOCXvDEkz@vya/Iyz4yiGsXRWxWAAYre6R@puqJuAgjps3isP1jHHOpBbDU7ciS/PWTGQZjBBSQXfwWci@wDzHsg8PByVTkAiB10m4E0PqgmEZONVYrUB2DrJXGwYVqicUrBrd8MJbaLHPipXoE7pBO@DUMdjjCZiNCW4YWNfELk/csdcGVDbzJ8IdT4DvUauPmGDjHxtelCpPPoIP@7N2C2kez5IAA/iNlChyuGRa5SB7RcaDuB0dwTtVsdbx5V3FHi48esWhtjEGqha@Iu4PbaBiyp849r4FQ7vfLFKxJ0oV0O3ArDYjFsy1rO3r0r5vqAE/YT@E7HM6q5LwTJBSd1@fEkgrYrFazklwHoNUrSwPQc1NTbQwgLWJYA2vcOrDr61sNYG3Z3hLJ4CgbjtcfcYugTz5SHBhGMap57Xo2EDGQ6vvbUr80AAeoxRVGAGejg56aBLmj6NlzbTpHcPvCQHEDtCXaCaI9NLj3Y4rwj0/AxVPen@uFfQa4urIrkEhR8A1PdIeILKNtH9pRwY/I40m/To9G35iVchKzgs@N2UieimRPqjX8haOVSe67XIt9JIYqyfg7EQXZ4lTMLwwis0VJxO/fELfjnCazfa@cO2R/fe@BbICstYSN3o4SN/EOXxS4a6nIvCmtB6xoPluB1efMmrqCmETXHABj1sOBUNML/hNSKlZa2NXGPagi2syzdQVZmFmlFcll8ueWPXxKPeXPkOkW2Daqbplhxrx1wKPNfyKpPt2saDvuSuYrQhISVFILRqOV6/yytJVUeZ0BAUN55lHGp80VFgDWnuVDZT5ij@czvV8ElacYebNbUamT4ch6kjqkMrCXcNVd1lZd7A@mSx4adwuI4O4PBm40Y7Bl@nNsRU6neRpdWUNbyuJORvwT1uIkt65crsdUaHxkKriUd38hZRs1wGJHdoZcAVpo2ElKc2xj4v/RRTFankyeEO4HgXGExBmm/Ap3kZHoQF/VwvF2gQVoKQaMc46cu8@wB9p6279iDwpSszOli5UEDvha/3EqNWIFcv111n0sem4Es/lIkMVBatU6729ZZDqrn84M8jReCkdzhBHLz@C4a2oHKoz1YrAEUmK/KFXxZsqjtxRC/VqPvyjox7IJZbslrZB@XCCDtBD96GOxuSqt4du0fwZ9/DFvWCPPJL@uW7ktvmy8THe7uPDnb2W/s7X9nZf7JDJUmRXxsUT0ZVuikLTtG591DizQcxhzi598cenON44lCcJZTAn3T9MBT3Qdx1QRx/0YaS7Ymby3xzX3mQnfc0cMfrXP6AmXkyvidN48BDE6EJqipB/05ZAOfnYTsoMPHDGUgOqVDrdYCeDDguVA73TNjMOQf3T1xJHZ/iPhOEtGzAI8Xvh6fIAUppIv7GDCfNoAer2a1IHVsFjVcOkb8E7RABGQDIR63bWYVCj5trFQbeBZ4T2UhsKwcVBtn7Xk085mq3qVqxzf1CHrI98IdHOek9wWgBcW5waJUwsPm6GmIyCoIqUG8BPQXiSHOPuENVlA@q9Uqt@vm5NIgesX9D3grewCT/De28F@30U@MnpZntqxgABo8zT9jQxcImpVrQpUdrihvUJSpakRW9mTl5tjW5RH/9N2xBnmFALlu3@sUYjX@@9tyXNrP@zD4WvngznFQCjlnlKPJNVTGdf34GO/9XrEZez1zkIiuKL00n0k0nZEC11zGeyC/nSfsYOY/dPb6wx6smff0TKO1uGc4owZOpXSumaKsj2MSV5qN4NFIT@XJK9DEN@pha@a9NHT67rym2AFF309WOX6PXhnFErKO119KE14F6LlBxN7X157H2q3pNtX1UaR/PkPeMLtJwzcnmxlWkabd59UrE1MDZ0oV1fIn8pYa5Nm9RTuWNyziljC7PDnVnxiUT6u98KZhSWgd5C2WMLA6vFQ8xJ6nVtEmUcLVGTCFeylEFhWu@OH4JtfVoBKPLUnIiZl7iy7bayzg2GIiKzga0PSgk5yiGMrqMzUIZnxo1F1mVyYW2YBOiX@D/v1hbaRJkA48vjax@g0ZWX1qNfGk18qXVyHlWI0tXq5NgXO14wyqwZgNRPgXuP7cEC2p7T7z/3p0DcfDejrj/9N5vi6/tPRXv33kEKXvi8dO7D3bvCfj/zqMnO4IK6H9fcceoci9g6rfdrku38yu12qogzAsBylfFk/aJeM/vui@BeDaC9snWMX9Uhm64yaV2Xrrjmc/PQSNUZgml1QTdFfFbk7pxQovrDlDyCb4jKl@e2Eby5hnwzRLZXlA4dG3AzW97xIOQHhc9K2mjDYD3IRXQtPlJlnSn8WmdmJZeRciB0/9eewSBKXz4RNx5tI2RPrd3D3b3Hj0R9/f24fPx19DNjtjeRbcxd59iFgE@3Nvevb977w4lcANqFYF3a2Swfl4TKghOo9J90Z9geLABSoXyK@bVeymXG/rKKiIQ@ckwct/TA5LCd3d2dtogF@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@YxaO20yhruwVqJ41g3W29dI@4yi5@@AzfLomaSDYrKW5gL054xKDOjZaYxuXvoCFYtmIbWEgzvkor3jYxFUmx@sOZvbd5@VP/6wdFitHvG20O7x4wUrJfIzC4nksDy07iRpA6qVJpHmgkkHSyt9Rt4tcZUrZMC4HHvAfG@1GjqPr1UX04cULyueTomvXjlcqkz2JkRCGEkm2t1KoqmqLFGZQ1GQCKK9ExqLnnVVSolw6v16C@Pa4yw0YESGuI@Qeo0ZVo30awxv1/igBztLTvJpPN0af0HFIpcURf9scz6qH9h3neJmoaqgaDHp4bTVFl1SmOsF2as5Ti@dVwvots9HB/v35dGtnds6Ph5eC9v2udheq23lYjYuPpYMXJdH@/E5aPlweyO00PdSNmI@JBexaUrXxFm6tqRo/oIaP1yYO1p7gAbPXoyoqpEatU2GA/QQZ/OlODSNChRMNBFD9ORge2d/X1g7eMu2DmVh32sPu2Rfitsg4r6qPB2xHTJtdhXNNOkwQZp5UilzNi@NV3veYk4dvIytQvIgJTkeerPQUXtBMplK6wg@WYiFQMNr3hDVyMVbd6b2oKApEc@bqAklokkzOphL7eYSHz7sZJ82mWjcSswbBy@8kWZm3Kl01kVX1eOZiUgxwngctI/w5Tt9/t5n/nhd1cMMlvv1CXUYlfC76C9fPIGKR/hSXInP4DnToqaUdFaISpfU2JFZXpzD/uwEpWOxzyUvbGzrkjmWTWP@@JoRyY740y1855/JzO6JvO9UWzylbJgTWogOPTt@BAGTCWKw2DKpAoofzuURRqOhz0lHM@TmWrtGrWmqVlI0M4m7kQ30FnDwN24mt4dkVbDbnltV@fOpik@JWE1G3K3FGlQmYL5548b1i3Ane6GKlz8rbj5DkvtneDJ62TZQBrOAVIWAcncflVR@RADnDJ0DUmDPVgsmURBYnZQzJdZ3OozM9kFbTsdoiweN2Xt6UML7omStBTFNtC0dO59IJnYCWeiDsYR1R3nVLIz@/Pzq7lJQtwvqu/r69fFiQyC8D5//isNk7vsj3CqBER@32CsqiOTrAWrFhViCgw9qT79GDMwtFceyyfHmtviFG22kucat0H@Bev0qcqaMbWbhM1TlpD06e4UXXK/oypTz0CZAlvVKYus566hwZM2tnk9KBH0dynKLWxlPg23@ZcsMvrmO6oOUxwDGA6ajBzD/dl6A3LOOtwoq1GS@yGnAn@ikMicBrYYoe@j0ZU5HuwRvNJjp9Cqn91wMPKdTNySW07aOeJnflJDJCJl5SwLTXa3Xn7Vo2HX2O5wNbIxOeks2BmTLga9Tr3Iq6lSppKYsO4mSDjkJJCmdtCSh8GDyQpOWAtd90aJJltHmAGG@JIbe4LAi9afesaXsWJAmHCFPJJR3h70cTQrFPNWo1JGwha5lJQk1t7zDCilQyg0IZbJoYnkhbXlRARMY0o3Ql0xUXIwagP@VjZBNNYkXa25uPUcKH7tBd@KKnSnK@Co2oqJKcgyyJHYebYu9@2J/7/FOHDW2uIU8CpVSCnsUilk2jLqjlmwJJtyfhMctTlSfydxTl3MVCv7WQEN/bADxZzJXVUAoDnFZirNXvVeiCYf3SE@K3SscyklXPdZ9qHT9yTA8ezV9RdM7BU6vAiTwjphX8JLgnYVhkStRctiKHOgtDsNCIl/ZUm4VoloohWqZSt8cvrS4Tqz5wlxiy@n9E6YOViZt0lFATtgmcSfwkeVZl/EtYTi6x1HATXrLdoRtJxuGh1KlspBcFLd04EbXjLgbr@ySlRSzKrkdVcIUpvFUAowjGtVWED1fvPJeqcqiQwWP/rWktKNHG303y2k0jhhadjGY2qGRza8SRp97ufivhQUnZ1DE443K1w1eEBjkPdrNHabxGBjR9wKY3hwUGC@gBThaBTFAXiYLgFR@EWMrvZXR0kspkt7iaD0uNiejlghdSpH0WqJGx6ciWuuJ2ej6wJ1xQBL80QJB0DhfU2cOyGah4qzFKpIFJSmSONPiOm3@U0ipQ23TDAH0eKh@1g/Z9EbkzWLnwsdHxGyB7LwxILgHkTsVPNbM9Hoy3TySxKZRPAlhNCoBDDgTJ9XFc8GeRGJJp2ipxcuKjLZkNHDkteTRCFvOoQFKJJQBWo6D8qqJYAEUQYiLw5PFAOWVGActpoMaxE/wJtZEW43VqEGL6aDG@ljAWk7DGgctJkEX9jXaKONjrxnaZfv8yStk8LEmOqMqd@p2JyGfNMppBayhEJaHyWhJ6J535IXviIjRol8VaA8S7eqa9Iit0kDAv3FLsz5UQLHaZhNktRFC3C0MXspLqZivo0z2LWLMNfMYg@cQ1/g@boA2CcKcBsEemGRDFJMhBRp1iilWzBwaLjUNRYOMkYQlls7gc47cb3PpjMUdjvxulazC3OJmNWK7KPRJJUv5aGNDjUUl9FueSP3XkI0nHP5IxHFUoqRz/sVwTEKdilccpYHf5cvOEuJqKGGtCekogNPDTgIHvqYs9kUVBDSHF7cDH1QWcWATiuK8Tpk4lFC1iGP50jiUwLaIo3z5dpA8ldaXty6NgwXBNBzVS@NAClwcU2vpDBDM@b9WGqnFxgPNomRqu9SJk4bG2Y59dZJ9UaKqQHtBwhCDnya@0tohGXOT1geGGHSp8UChY3E8bI9X0iYcxbRz1/iCuY4lCwvrhYVbSuUbWGPlNcS1IOzBQVDpD/T6Tln8CRE9cUkiEdK9Bwoxle7xGEQknM2KlD4UA0I4of2tFqpmtVp0M/R4f@/d/TsPW4/uPEQhaon3KLy@QW0ZUtepVVYwnj3ftrRIp8gRqGqB3cjRPmzkUfskmh06RShyLJZaOjPg5hYzUFiTQ/dFlaF7Ku5DFgWtX8CJkBV9NwPTY1Mb9KZulV9ahQjSPMFUr6S8tgktIRimE9kSgjGSc4awxeWfDVlD5dnwWciAHdFkm8zg0GzvMzRcMgoKUX75LPyKO@6gLklZOy3lWUQVfJTdyDkVqlzIG/QIgzGBv6pWxV3lFFfar7UHXXR5O@mT49sTb9A@6fTaldHxKNcPHOmexs73A3RymUNlqt2Dnf0nrccYp2vnHllO4L8G5R3sPtzZe3qAOU8g67pM3tnf39tvkYL6/tPHB@gxNJFkmYASSwQmE2JAj/beu/PAgOFvSzaSDUICkDfhj3TlUxLeqDWl/87IzKPEqhAtCsJDZipYlNJKIvROXH@igreh/wl1wJfQ8gQfZaAuFdWYHNLYeP0p8yJfp3MDitoxnoxCAiUNeDsxEoV4CYY5CY6wAPkiCoBvJ236Ct8oYx4a8vkjO1EWDWSwWE7ad/UDWh24TJ7Mhl1boZOOPEtn7hAg8bUpPwn75bX8vIBeJUekNJQsnK/CyVEl56j59JJyBKVWes4IYmReuzZyyuAdoMiihCYhskyhAvyC2BDFolc4y5kBomQW7KocP@pMGDb0cRgZv@aKMUfs1pT1fKF@JBD9S1rgaBrhz8fmoxQRmHyfImOOJlqe6zGjv6qzfMNs69mx6X0qsuuuoPbIPWjwndBmRy/ksy@iO/ncJRvQwozkjMfzAL18G5MdpgqZxoOwAQMVjmeCLQiDUA8X9PwQ/zuVrl27qEBjA8EVTFjL4lx2R4lGQkHIACTmWZvWeuTGhs0StOIwQ2yYEPU0iA9MiJU0iJcmxPU0iE8/YRCvbxeLavI2xcqNG6zNHJvPlOL/pouXywp2Q6lCR4UBn1lcncaMZIdxSOiig@ag5pkNyM2W3Ty3ZXHUn/474DZxyVJlqoQbfk6zz8H889@z1vmG7hKj9NfcQ2ODQuZEPnmxCTPeF96TJK6aJG1Jk9h@cg42y1KzmF72uxFFfJBBNJ/@NAaTTjbfVvMu9PipF64rUdl6ZNWQRPAfiwic10HQ4vJqfZG3UTbgxeyVdY1F9SBCwCDXTZCVJEhala/OrbJm4qunVlk3QWqXqfLTn8k65fmVAvFDDUF7rRzMVND/ii00Us2HQmmgAUOiTc3j6NU3E/wo3gazWBr44wg7FTk8v90//0ay3VHJVPjfTyVOKmDSl5r21IH/h8viuJ6J40NGUS5njlueIYrFTIhPfxS1g4c3uczOWyQ//8OLS9eyS/9uVDo65jfVwc1cg0KW3AK1elA8k4o2NTaePxgAnZLSGuMY1WvOWHJ4FkuDsXgH6jpbWpzFs1dU9iw1@7rOTiCfM4OluCT0r0eM0QZHGCTWKPpNVr7McKnMTcfk2grcIZPbZWZdGpjD2GgeR5riGEzPZkLgWI4JGYuoZW5BMnvzHHHBjVThJ2iP28fDNgZoDfxhRUYA8fzqzon/3MODalxFNxeV50GWNPRZWGtCQHKcg@LrHVSogKZKpyKs@81yOwK2u93JyWSAb2iOlKvQMVK1ii7jSBAcTk4CiRNP3LsTbwA9cJBTi1hEEPNG0Eo6hYGVvlT1iarTql2sslplvfEKuaGjJGpbd@yNQqrMWZQF0OUTMahQhbdhwCoWHg3UzwgRu6J1ZH8eeEPXNuAxiqtXMhLIL0LR4VINoozkmBg4SqgB8mhyEsNwJmecdGMczqkEaPFj10orOHIu0o0YuxghRFtHeIFYkT7oyLUMIpEWROM4lpXSaoFHiRA9BvI8iUOsllZqWNEIs8hFEXmG1prl7T65LSKjVsJB2DQ0zQJwhBF6Oa6bNegdZOh2OdYv//aTv7MKZ9WqSqOYOt6wDTIDRSSJsOLngf9YfRvoUT6RtooJ3H8f4WbUPbfrnbQxQk1ooAbiysAME4iYz4DQ0GmVP4D9xj@yDV8wqkIkrGr1zva2OHhvf@99tIbiSwSigkRxJIJ1YRV52KlkLF8qBiOIpIRFmIeyYgRSjViE0r1CMN1jcq/Ttw0NLBitb/4xjRbd5fuo6c7rMoEQsy126oP3hKhba6LVE6EoGOfhm3/EmP0Ra8@mI/ZHliRM@DlygfjVVaS90C@GSK/vF9//M6pOWpQAz4f3Kidm1VlMP@U25YUs0Wy5fpjZq1g1NAiZiC8com/9mJAFHKRbbYS5K@auqJGkd/uHfyUIBz4@wOwZJUUMT/FCRN9mRPr1gEYuE1/5QnzfYXw9j14BTESdWbyLD@GcrIzRaMg2kqsXDN8vvi9bDPBeiG8m59SxHGtuLnUy/tWcWSorpyNrfg38mTP8AxOpNHPNwsgHVSqeT34WLVOzm@w6men7irE6E01L7fAn/5lGfaRjDqsHPYAzWnOqUtdKRpv/4i81/mnuyvQCgvnl337vR1Efp5k9m2b253vRapou9mKa1fYriS3pq3hkWMVp5lT8NF5NbOVOHeMzC8FPssZ9Gh/sadaSB9LXi356wbLPQvJthUQv@OmFSz4L13cUrtTFnuxWxnKfZi5zhT1joSfwL2c0Exbjv5iLcXrezGeu@Wyy@BtCjgwfGo8uTEu1KjmcGrG2G6JOf9EzL/7dTLbG3P3wqi1iXBzgqAAdSk0x2kOo6Ya58s@SMeXnzNdEqXXpbEH1yKilLmsB0aQ9CFKqcpzPra4VHDoQ91Jq2XyzSnLzanXostH9ZNRDqYPe705I8hjT8x8GD0jfGb9BcwncNogrbG1D7gma1ORDesEJFsgH0ZHPISVqoAfoHogb9HdDd7dc5xSSN64ksQx8Zomu0HU6ikKZgoiUJIr1w1ShguXU1IXwT3oHYumqw9IVDpbsI/mRjXIu3Ly/9SO9I@lR8uPYEyiLF@P8RzkNpGJEb@XksUPydNmondiXFqTiqeoIyDy6/9ncLRLVZfOSBlgW5u/@iT7o3AB1WXvQHzR5JY//GBwTBybzBDT2T/5JCOzCcrRlZNb8p2riA96hsirHk@wS9WRU8@M/sJC00weJsxsXC1kSY6aMJXYfiadPdvbF3tODx08P8ELGdIyoZfBsQY/Fbt6XSYCNXxIsyLINEPNXWJw18pi8vJJXXClQ9//8e9h9Rlt0rJplDNO55X4QK1dX5c4ZI5qKS4@QHJ@F8nxpAa3jumVvHWdNjhAI0LvDENdr4MIPCcYXE@zwWZ5tTP5sMm1K3bJixnOJqf88u2VcxmRfJuBRhxPg1AXOn1P7kjK@GMqgK6sZvt45aa95jB96oVx@EugXTUGxm830C9/T09NKH8NTTcZexQ3QPVGAjuGqoyNgFoY@XWqi22wgPK8Lsi06L5x0X0S/yt328GU7QAWZd6aoEu3cfnvGf3NZd8SjoxMOxfGm98RC0G1vaVbqlgBZqdN9Ueqf9hoygw2DtcIJJyL3M1YfJ4H65Y36GsIP8Z5dZ3UGL7r@gLhdqzOAg8yKquYeKsiZ@pTfI48NY9Ql8kx6PxXENNusSCHw0YBy4CdwVcq62Js2Z4ex4lNdPKbNEnBEzHORskIw5rMeB4UNmHL@NKpUVducSmfx2oQMXx9QKURBIpqZgolZhGPOlJXiN/GFCtMQchZLQ8ufrkOl1XjzF8yjowgDaGIEA@7a1eYHz5rPDoeBe7p8WKweldDREUJ3pFkjjSn57OHfOPqDl4ORH8SShm4QsoJLTSV1jyU1MK2w4oscq4TGDTRLK9x40aChdqBDmbhF3wltT5qpkjbOMT1vW00rGmNuWFM2BkfaU0oGMg0fngxTexPRoYEI03WXVCS@NF0o6/0x@tNSsGUYc3QAM5yhGSEGaogvFRnDVMzjrcLXMk6AYWcfuImuqHyYimYiy@jmXM6/2fyrr938PqyL9NYTwfKmmFAam7qw4bpyubBHzE3HmFdoQXW5PUCXf9bOkNzTKMXBQmO5qkxTuB7sggw6a0x@Vzqe4JfUodRCwbpmKPuKmcPLkteFGlKtaRK9wlO@IgRZnjcQjiCSUsyVxaZmMZB0eeOgZ7G0YqdGI6fUyCkXYehpRiMPZTEM5Gm6bThEp21tOI8AX501ekksFEH7JcanYldEy1VdZ7TnEBUoC0OYUKSz7mFq7U2j0camlUCAhLiAoOf225NBuJ5Lbnj1sv7SexQPpdqj@EuSAe8VQGC0BTdYqczWRCZfLPAq3SO3l/CrmbPqpVqpTv@r8f@tkkpU/68vJtbikPV4Yq2U@N@vJfEQRzZdLKrXVnFDzv1qSYxm4bE/XMktCX1mCzqz0R8hv6A@D/h9OBh6o5EbUpgjceQO8XEbA796Pt5YoPMvjKsDv1@45F9kXSEX/BTbeh60EFFLIqqMZsK6tmXBuJ@M/HEoPhp4HfUbY5TfXFVfwSxAN1KB6xIPFAATJJ@5Ud/3YDzbDfeGeC9RRY/Joc@/OwO/Uz0BUd4dkyvHANY8QHh@ZTwZVsndlDvs4bM4mSG0X0DTjqE66FqvBWAt7JZdQMoLXHRPaT2b9vsWOW9xB70nLjJueHskdCSV3R7xHe3g2MJtbUk8AiZsnd2tKB8m2ksXjbgr8vIxrjzgeM6kMZA3In2hxjvGsiTNDAuVouV7Pbn@syr0AA2lrAKxZXaBTkQ/jOCVKqcswIohsRLYRwzSx4wxnhVRjzBEqIuWJbIRRSFkArUj@pSVRglUkTyfvRKwh9grZUXr2jCtzDPW19G9J96VOfWC3ik8tJOqr61jbA7qCQ4oTpN8Gq6vYQ45qAwERpxj3zRmP4qObAkA8oRQIETgscfokaHznJRI8bIODg@kv4rKw@uJDrpEG1CMF7y/GrpHFCVFnHY8DgXT8wICwJLVo4@8kRyiUoxUO5MjYLVpLVBkFS8IJu6NW2ur1CCKa6RAe343BrpSBczoWrZKjTsOTwa6F7fDYzFwX7oD9v/GzabYL7woic5suX3idfPNApEODGWspzAK9u0Sp23v3H9w52BnuyTK9RsIzgaqGtY2Bpezi5RPBhySjLAIL99K5@YqE7kdlPJb1XxBNn3LHPai2WCFAPasMcpxIzvvUDF5M8eIQWTq4V5V0vEWdWw31NXG5YZNmYwxaoGlBlet/KUlC0ka61pCEoxtjlCmEB0a8AUbzwJQ5l4BIyB3txYKYRhKiCjX2rhaLus1tU6/yrCxlsubbGdu3QM5/IXI70@Gsd02T2unLfKwyaG3PN7aruZpX6hYDXHs5N8K8g3kzjXn9NKeFM5UiL9hH1th88Ad@Hdnav7sidJagQEpNOuHhYJMyP/Pf4PYN4/MAgZ2WDhD/vojR7mErfCmvsMeNO083wZDsY8qoTsN79HmGjphQxfo@L1ZhUKS9u7B2duzPzLrGNmFM9Ju7jrO9cIZVDkeoR3KCDZD9wAwFhqY1o@lRSLHs2dDdIu7jPLXVx8@eA@mfB/9SwVh84PD5WvVUj4PRzxpIDkY6UNs7z18jDcJ40KFbhTuj/0TOS7jtq6kgg/7aDlMrS9Z2LUqrkLYOY/cUPY@uDs7aB89ap@AxNyGIYhf4LRNrR8Mc4@6/OYYOVZ8cq3C2ZFDUMdjt99gTmgeOC/to0IjhD/HZhU3oApnZYWwh1DIQQcCiVH3hnBav3fw8IGT32gLxOqkrIp8saOJAwiFCMbGJBJoY6SD4XSRqkK22ySCgX/FvLUZ78tGtb2Zb8znme154Ld77PErHxFwz56UJMWNncUpbYwjKpiNXAcT@Gh7d@fAKkFZlH0xkWIczWjTYmfEjqqDyQ13CjoCZ08QxnFW336b0rDIJHCclVqtgOohc8BGPiAALS@scWM@bjs9Ww9ke@RV6OrcnXJdxJysVFaq7WFwCuxotX6zdvt67R1/jO8GPTfovh3AFuK0MaSsF87eRkN@Uic78gf9t/veAB@srq4ur@15d3/nq7ef3Ny2u53fAh7Seh74@IA/HpkNGLdPpfYf7LHjLlMXNWIIOLvt6qj9wq@u9mrdtdpa/VbPvXXDXatdX@vecK/f7ty@fbvbX13r9G7fat@60e1U0W00FamckPKgxeSP1fYvV20WY7a2Urvd79frN2/1btzu316pXb@@2lm70autrvbX6u3r12/2VtY6tzvnc21Re3Kwwap9F8@O5A78VjZzl1vY22Xpwv8C';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=
#*  
#cs
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvw/WWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 6  \=>axfnuen le._e=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Num un Cr Uu8 gutyIO  
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>m=unsafePerformIO$0?error"<"`catch`\ErrorCall{}->pure 3;data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;_?_=pure 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,212,211]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a)+l 1e1+k+m+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 34);instance Num ();(! )=seq;f= (^)
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on BMO's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153774) [adjusted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167389#comment404683_167389) for polyglot by Ørjan Johansen:

```hs
import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe
_?_=pure 0
main=print$unsafePerformIO$0?error""`catch`\ErrorCall{}->pure 1
```

Test above code [on TIO](https://tio.run/##Xc7PC4IwHAXwu3/FGF4d6ikS7SAePBlI0CHQNWYbuB98N6GI/vZV1iE6Pj7vwTtTJ0Jg1KMKTUS4iDNhUKIRzvLNFuECwaIvgv1hnuW/mBx7D5L5TysEqawBj2qjPZiZNFfGrZdGF1/ob85zRdqOHLSjE4@G3VDaBThKI0WlLi1I7eNlxT2HyYBquzjdcQADGI@vw0yMp@YdazrP90dSrfvsCQ).

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>m=unsafePerformIO$0?error"<"`catch`\ErrorCall{}->pure 3;data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;_?_=pure 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,212,211]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a)+l 1e1+k+m+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 34);instance Num ();(! )=seq;f= (^)
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
```

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dZRtb9owEMff8ykM5QWsBCVp13YYZxqFqZX63E2bxlpqEiex6tiZ46xBwGdnl7SdOpFFysPZ97s7/33OnGbxZuNTgzwU9kWcNZgfK2RJ1HLcowFqYaRzGcU@svw03XI5tLdcrO8XLKKG/2Zn3DBNRbZNuTXUdU4zfp0rw2qA/RrgnEbcP4H637i/YY4@1DAjKqMraqAuuZXFtd/XEVxSvfjfUlz7oIaZFIbJgAVjFtJcmJtcsBrysIb8lKaC@5V6Y1W7LteuW9dFnoyZz5O6Ep3aPVLnSqpE6TTmWXLDMqO5b7iS27hTpz3AZ8qnAuQJalLWbfBtleLFd7PxeJIqbdCYGtr/nEvfKN0/VjIz@GXmCytM/4RpFij/dQwcjFaiPyl8lpb1vk7cLjLDkv7pZf@rzGjI8NL6Zq05hKPSZ6gsmAeIEg@@aNCpEiHafYohPpp5HpmRhCWpWVgWGsLV8P6yIC4aoWfPUKvkVBoWMY1mZITgBGBZ9jsrzXaxUzS8hORVCVdMh0onp5dt@yPTWunWsPUAm@vHDz8npX1MhViuLS/NIfIeDkAJNCKjZT4YQI41jsi0TLoqH0Or5bXuLGu6umt4BbHxYoeSLJ8bTUFUe@5AK@ICxuCwYAELFUxGJm5nsXpCFMdoTub3BX4kIbLbIXLRwT6efZyRKreNK55Mobt60DA9OPs9GID7EGwXbueu2eyIjlETCXLYg0GpCshZmfCm3V33negECtGhVak7de5wFR2mBHKYs/u4m1ROMUp5L@5AkBtGxTPdtdDefhf/I3qniztN1CUZ@4VDgjr3XRCXcrkSzKC0OSM2STWXpp3lydRuHji9pTWz1oJmpl3@ZKZ5e2qVhduraNj6AfqBgOvGHw).

Comment: Hm, come to think of it, `k` can be rewritten as ``0`f`f 2 64``, which can be inlined without parentheses.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks, will add it to StrictData. Is there a way to merge [these two](https://tio.run/##dY9Na8JAEEDv@yuG4CGhZNHYQ2mIHowHTxZE8FCI2@2uu5DshskEEqS/PX7UQqn2MDDDe@8wH6IxwyAFwQw0Nw1T0niIHQST5OUVghSwdQcj/8BkkvyG8W5DaCXdWc@PrFyQ@DaHwVa1R4KFd4S@5MtOqpqsd@kNbPqGVMVXa751jdCKfV7iHER2nlSHORRRVreoYMyKefGzdpBBew3eFGqP1Wo9Gs8Voscg2J/flWb/vrycC1GWx694dg0T1j8IQ83z0a2N/o@nrBLWZTVaR2H31Ecn) `unsafePerformIO`s into one? I don't want to use preprocessor because it adds parens near start of the line, which looks ugly.

Comment: Most of it can be [factored out](https://tio.run/##bY@xasMwFEV3fcXD1GATLBq3Q6lRljhDpgRCoUMgURXJEtiSeJLBJvTb3STNUNoOd7icc4f7wYOeJsEjLEBRHYgU2kFhIZmXL6@QVIC9bbT4Bct5@RMW77uIRsQ/1vN/Vs0j/zanyXTeYYSlsxFdS1eDkD4aZ6s72I0hyo6uN/TNBq4kOV3HNXB2SaWyGg458/BIPPM9ShLgcKtNall/W2wlKofdevPQZBLRYZLkx8thoY/71bUvedueP4uFB0sGFtKSjCxTtM7TJ9JxY5lHY2M2zMb8Cw "Bash – Try It Online") (Also abbreviated `pure` and renamed `!` to `s` since using an operator there only forced more parentheses.)

Comment: Another realization: you can use tuples to get rid of some `l`s, like ``l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+k+m+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a),do a<-Const[1];pure a)- 39``

Answer (score 7):

## 220. [Ante](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ante), 10409 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM3@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WHLKtpx2pm/pSzozbX1KSqIk2hTJJClbSqc/VNcsaqem@6GnprbRl52uqt7t3V5ggGks9qEH04sFpl8HjfkNXz8tGgvUP6g95wRJURc7nV9VY2eBoS0yGHHiRMSJEydO3A6bktX7zW@CeLEjXR11Vd1mtmzZrG0qN7KZYBsj9lxSrGw6EwggVNXsDvqyZlvFQJCJjClaS2nDO7P1a1lTPskm@KcZM0y9a0p9Zvckm8lWSzJki@kD2xjYTO/Mj5ZhrNbXr5Q4xuwrWhfAbNk0TNmm8BXGzjRV6jfb0lRIdipBw4Rwi23J6uf@Z5u19H5f0toWQOYY29dNS0b4lmxZOkZfZWxYk1tTSPMAKpmKvlc9eDEVVGDsBWRRMlR5yKSmZZtSy1Z0DWmSYicHZydHUzFEkb053d6e9k2zV3FdY9uD1vV0UIadmZakStP4V1h1YOu79rR/llW7siaxdKKQSE8H5tiGKc1EWWWmLLU7iionoEJYnPVk1ZBNhj6so5tsF7Kk5lP5VKM6jploYdz8OHAabYGpmYw9VZ50Cgivmz1ZgxympgNFL3AqIO0FtBVKQDJHLGz1dBP4yGQDS26zW91sA3Np6igSg/hs@Ik1JUvOrSCCjIfgWtNvNWAiW4eqbY5smWm6FqfICLjCxL3GNGOls@hbPdyd9s@x9N603yowWuu6M1uX6Tw71o3RtG@B7St789g5k@INYVNvQ21MhYnsSAIvSmaS8Jn0ZCtoQe1CY2ZXFmSsLTNLUwxDtnkg8IpsUjDEZqqiXfMGfmTq7UELG5/dkyFtbLDID1agBbEqzHDERAIdLEgcxMEgByd6X/bn12KaDBVkGXJL6Sgtzljy0JY1C7JsJZgChbhVVJW1ZRUijLG3YszSsXrHXk1V6iVaiQAyJqbC@tcqU1jLMBgPglJAlrZTeSYj9dgnCFd7FhsafWYpfQi2W3qnI8vsk2z0IHqgrQcYXC1jqlje25IMMJrskkY2QCAgaXSkNNDJpdCtKQFpTcuhga30gbCKHbKYLFkKClSIYslam6hqeKJWZ9IEy7MbBRo8FH1gEm5LNqnJEV5onqYMKCWvmsO3pmLb1GpYlR3JkslOTVmOTIrdiSQhMR1TsLEgCarUtbVQ7XA7BJXLYyQkAyrTzJy@fhmQWKLMlhol@JUFoRSoHWyxu6VLdHMpCwxgmGEpwsrfMSt5eSnDbyg2k13zPgBYA0AVlSV1w05KcQMyGLchg0kJneiK36QThupLmK1N1YWP5ThUG2oDhA97E6OStQamiT3JmKjSNRRa1bUu0BMKaw40pIfGcimogpYOHUGMyTdANZC8VEcgF5DCpz0FKs3CKvE1LN4fEkGhRwQ2dijqpmvp6oDgIKZlIy8DVSAqYtztsDesIykqRoFwRMVzbcrWQLUxzkBrY81Dfye3E8zNBjVYE/j4BpKTACl5AOv3fe2SMgXAUBE6FRWDvv/DP2t3u4Cn2mqBbHPY9Q1r6y3quSXKLHSHDBkWBKpK2QK4GKbOo0MCN5KqtElASNrISYIyQane6gO1zXRI0LxVoJX2pBto2dC4WrbMmZx39jHWl665NFE450LB@1ITKpYSoLSp2HH2fBNqqSUHgsQz8f7A7uRZ3KixkJX8NrxeDK8vXsqQuUgisryUTHZLwHCJZfKCt9BjnPOmOiEpLVuydKUdMEZ2T9fSLN5iQqusG7IWDk3gCMVCZjMUSaCUC0dKSrmV6ChaOxxaA16sQMKhSKlVbl0oxXppKro/SUBzi2iwucrhVkQIgMihRnGT7IM0T0Dn8CbuuHxhutVAkmNwwueNhJn2u@EeQVJ2kC91ZBCQQwlLlWUjnEqIERQTCDe33Bgwr6RTOJwCF5V6NBQMRf1FJwxQ0omCYmM9VXQUW6rRw04LiKJZBvQEJvJuC3pqlIyWYoPGGWNN4mvqRUCykEy8lUOmjF26x0fUJHmTw/hxFJQOhnETmmzJctvXkEEIQFu2rRlprOq3kCDlCbsZEB0aJip1oWogMi9IlReEp0Q@k0XiigZga8osH28q0AiwuYFMd3jeVzYAz6Q5DGDjjcQne/rSCLC0eLc6bjBM6UBb6oN4AG2oJaPMAeEj8w4FExlQ@7NAx0ZtOxVPZ7OTbWymidlmshp/D0L6U/LRloSF9zcmFDSsI98yVdK6A6krc02MSa2WbNiOoIKSWDaIoun@hjzjTueZsHqBpefTaVMn4qoW4zRQyPPac7pCCaWLo@jHQZ2RmeQMVUBzNEEsqaPp1AHgZipx4QOCTGTgg/BAFlwNAJhMHsqtgQ1SDRj4tqe0esCzmDuNy0XeCU0nD17@1EGyxzte0pgZsfIsHUgkPS/MxoMo4lijs3igc0VUlQkPqny/x@OYJas/B7HuZRE6Ap9vIiklgPe@gLOva/ocpEBIDy2CTIbwegBN7AQVSui4XLWLGqunZXpVBHWGA4E28l/Ptg2rCP2EYvcGzQRwSvLUHO3ahxoyS9I2R4qtc3dT1Zsgli1on0k3hWRr0FSGUwUiP68Or6zADShgHYuVoef@OACuC4c6FghM8t9EYF@QQIKbUPC7AIAElABChTsWieJtEConI60VFhLUlBLQ6IQYE7DhCjDcETCWR5dNvY9SiJ2TYoCaHgz7FA3HCo7MJ5Evze3qPNlPel0olLjSFS18F1pcXAwVQxWQ7IuL6@BaQ9c6uqLgWidXnFwIl0AXxYiRC0MvKAb61UP3Fy7mYaSO1TbEXumTYoSli2IxU49JF6LzTOMzAqIOJBtAx/EBeEKRchmdkYhQuYWCJpqdydJvonQ@aZmK4RDhpXQj8XeHChkig9I3cBhpyiXsZB@nSb9sQi8ISmurFzZDlxepy/rl3WU7enkfimHsSEkqN6FQkF64n@ia@gC6y8jFSjEu1iORiwx0ks1yKBVaDofzcRUSkiKRb/KRqMSpHQ7JILXDl5chIKpDn4tWzyR8w1g6EvFIBfnAjhl0wnAocZeH9JuReiQagriRUAyGGOVQCCjTQiJYVGjkzAkCHR6/4oTZjEYDxIa6eY2/GbEPfgkYYPHo28C/myeTw97@NUhX1rJUVEXiJtdG4DW5zD3b9PA0riLbJY1Vg@4WSgC9bdsbGeFoXBuQ/kzKre5PiIaDCEF@2PegXFUmYBBxRxnCAAHa/chVhLD/Rl1oEwacuionzkk1ERg0HBz2yom52tAR71YSLWvMA6D3gNNQpRY07El0lwK7BITA58nk/JBIaQbxtKpEo5ovlRE6lpakIf3aCmntA8XqIXlBs8KhhNkBqqLKDrqBTFTbZS3o87tAaXmo2FyHBz46wSg7khWOoNZY5VoXKnuoMWCm3DkA6s71Fox3ZNAcMJQPHllNu1FMXUMiJ2qAGhi@hHUwhXweeYGNqtXd9NbD9J2HHCg24y36aOvHOk3cltViSU1X9a7OlgEAWTOR4Iy9q@FUCeh8NgwvmaV8IgJVu7o2muJBGbt7C3VEMZfxtG8JIZMEn7gCWcPmF3oM8ECZT3bf16CHELOpFOTffUvR5RXSh2W6jOjZYmMAZ8pWRb7BmnwvG73RxIQS8gcfRQI/6TJvmHxcL0GHCrlyWvgniupv5NwH2rkb1HZd88peIw0JpzL8o4yJ0oMyCO3UKQ5vNlDC4JQ3@rqkmEA6U@Hj@kXBdZmckFvewCne6eu2lHyT6FkMbwHUF@IKE6xkaDGUjMfxLlAQS1dYsi3fJFFKOZhBKp/2BnJAbvV0JlyC7uIHEkCE9kAJj0MhZJPUPC@aMzkdsPUB6IttWVX6ir1LE2mqhkrRuMN3Q3E@cIzgSJHtgDOSGQtunOwaS3Gty@FrQ@zqrIBMT3ZwuFVrHFVPd8pCcmCZSVVpQttoy40@qLSqbAls@gqyYxmQOfE/XavHum6XOSNcq@yLVxDjuNH3thp7uxvH1eN3PBOExlL6A1XCrBSXpgAw@gkFu@3VN8PYMfW@p@tbTkUsZZD08sRqAg58ndAVDB04awk@/xz693F9INEKdFstFtf5q@fpAK4iIK4ZUO/YjUYRktYQPE8HMk8ocR0hYTZdzwJ6eisIE3PrY3Tzwh@O5GC@E1P3iNzSBpbhK9mdKJL/jd3poD7geafJ@zqOjUgde2fIm69ATM79O2SZCZoL7OFbIXx85WIuvpmgucAevizHhyse89FNhcwD9ZDlCBmukMzFNRUwB9DDtEqY/Ksq47A8hT20pOKkNTf4wUge7gLhxmWXMSpahHG8XMA0544@XxKxGjj7OuaRtDgRikF8IYXF2zDsWUMQ5JfPuMQCXqAfWkY7YQ/tMYqMH0UctBm@wOKFc0YQ1YbUgFY5zq3r4wticRUEmJgbR856kfWpqLoy9vbAeb2m1QaIgIGvSbs@/iAvEq9CdyXH3yjSvAZN3Rj52vJdmhO/rzjixNe6MpzcJIdQ7zInAjm1DXc1ZyKMN0u@gtO44tOADWcBB@uFC8JT6NT3dFDF9hSL1lX9kjHgDRkuA4I77plQ8IVxSHo8/8jiN/MnTgU/IpLZIFavdRxuj12NVELMIhYPRf9anY3ZAa2VbhOgM5maDeF9Rb/ZodscgKIzJwfdIi4yIVVe4roCThvqMIaQbwmMZhcIGVBL0aTkMT1wnmFefiZnTCYy05Q7A1CvkzD8Q/cXwOKFPEF2mk3lIVCgC2bdfc4t5PEAhjjpxEpCdMdTOEMJYyo@3XG6e0iA0H57M9NsbKIq7IFpQyzn@Z9@1IYqma2wnjSiQYbnaAAliVs6D9afExVf6Da/rgnmaqAqEhGGXF9C2ZJwZUNSPcd81KjTsHi8J5l91OWd6gZ2xRu0t0c4j@fclNVBW3af8xMpMiLy5HQe05Q@a82BJtipmUeeGI3eVF1qExn4GEuRKZKJlc2rQR7y0YZPmQVh9FBCcyYI2XhFzu4N7AG/4yLcl6pRMfD3EBEmYFNZqSnKSd2Smor8SLWb0vWgrceN6y4VGrOWmwM7Ln8T57PiHVW65s4GOucTgBfRVLpd2XSfD4Hd9mDYQOOd5C09HuEMV7VipCxLj@E0VX5/CMTdBuM5HqaTotLtCRXtMRSxSAsaCZIWV9rjPjIpU4RVpeYIx329r@csTJB0VpAz5VY0mspgJ@stq4zX9A3j4fjYM1P8QmF@bL7Gz0kyb8yS5Gv7cT7nRWV2Vvu/0Mih61L6khpPt33OB6W4O586ds0BpUmAeEuVLGAm26kO@Qaqj26PMTj2Ri1kq7HrEfYeZ8ddXXtoocZppU5LbumqYmFzVh@SmtNz2@M0cZcF3cZR8W2WsG1Sg61e3HPNlwR6y8ZVkgcY7QmSjS9Q4BKQj3MS@kNEa@m3@HtQuejpNzK/z@/cPs3N1RNkVFwlllBacwVou/UlTsWVdrrNp@P13HzZLXWuv7MeMDkUeCovW4qqWzAmx/tjpADt2rL4fT4X@6mmSFqcpq397vnRnEwZLOFM0z1Ql5La1dVcvpuU4PZghQ/MDkp@5/lUiedJLFH8ssRy9SBdE53ng6L@Omlef4kTaG7bxDUwn/ORfnae2HLWTh4uIIwfcGF7fuG2U3mKmUjyCZKHKsBs9W6lkfv8Ab3JQ9R1exNjRHo1qHkYoZAHh21yXfuHpLbyeGrtp4mkGbSrXyqEr3KvVRk6L7rPVClLp8SvjCGmUk8XUB11IA/kufLpsHkl49bGR0YbT89UyinGkjOVmATi4USiB/XJGTU@KdfYb@PbowJGUhVo5F/UbubKOwN0cQMH2kfgOELHbMSuNjAmKnditKYdP065nuG2bL09kUkM@VqJlP@yDjWhrlsy/R5S7Wt9HcbGeh/UBu0J9e8gpVkPfp9ATD5jRWNicmRu8t5COeiyoHpAjSrXVhznxZ8mdNIPDegJuFBIaoom2yO8P0TpeUK0qevq19QMyNK2QluY1ThuWv1SDc2oOc6eCTaeurBwGqTZeWjSgvczzuASqIfjZvuRkbJ/KuqR0eDMtPojvZVvkv1L40voqWlWyDJbrvshhqTJDzGRT6w@yo5cC9WbsirxxzC38hi@QiLzKD5P63DUW1qUwYUcvnQzXlULTokeYwTEUtowNunJfZleH1HqpfbVwHIfDwINdfzNCU4kaSHigXiGAm1dw/vEMpFPG7J1DUZTtmR2ZRyOqLgy6vg@JF/d9Y25xN3tS12Zn3B4THSMZyVwMx0fxI2d8@cninx/Swui8eX/x1kBGs61PLLc51yE@6MW1Oeg/@VZtak23sLZzy826kRy7rLOF9Q9raf3tJ7cM6lxeG8PNQ/gSJufTXmsEJD/nmRd4@5Bkkfj0VzP8lNX1VX1KdRFecilo67Pn5it4c7/NkT9KrwjqQkBzuOLM3bQZRORqO9@qO305AH0TJZu64Ycp7eHQFWc7OH3@XPNu4chi50rstnmWx9AHYeklaYqs1sFsnBl@ded508kNVVdwg2qjyjvQBn3@ZSpqZZufnHeoyvptmHQo2GoA4tuNKMbp3Ma84q7TTl9CjMoNt91wllW7urNVk/5UpaasmRrynXSncPhr4@OSx1hTCVXWHwLvROqArQyRwlkgrI//AQfuw/1f74lnLml3xyY5ujLgmFyxd@bauUrBOh4KH1ncXZOMHX5uK3K3T70yDKFs5b7IDeRAo3KclxOgVYiPjgDNLGDzJFetKj4gNIzVW7KjG8d7WumLp3NADSJp/g2NID/vMmLhwThjiPfYFQY3hl0rciXGbfXBp0Kb3MRVrt4WIuvJFmqfuubaIamL2nOY26v7K06PrYEkn10DSSRdNY64/LgwdktVTEsfmfxTnoultnF@1mo0fyRrlM9bbnDlynQ9SXNrq@buI0eVIh4y5StFs54o/TlUpGLHE3vghSOq2wM7MLOLcLsfoF5uslkDxd/eyB3JdxWt6fgDjvVmu30APP01oGnIH49kCzl9UC35bk4p7cQPAXlvtRVWjsTteAidKnr7MHij4lGgF6zFXHbUyzazew65jcczma0Gj8bOD2p7p2qe3wixKcXOZtKWXyXuZtPPQdO62O4NDetSa3TWYh/UNApNk2YOs@55Zy/3eKxWYTbQd8YWM5jfup9PJvgnznuX5O/dauAFIx/BKHLepJqz59d9k2egj7l9IRj50Na9ntF1bvsfT7FQP0CAYdK9wOMtQH98pFkQwvQ5jArpf/EdUucm4hzpcb6CIwgZ1hc0RT78XkY25ZgHOQ@sUBc1cKzN8k9vCeefy2G@Ol8quw9KvGhSx@1VBjZfAnq6N0XIOTNL3ctX1h2ga5S1wZ2HM8rPtZF5B7tIopsmM/5eICFX9f2zyIuK3R7Lb6X8QuamCXDiG5gqaOx68HF/jkcpuA57YeF7GwMd2iwJXekgWof44reU@JVDUPFmQ2Q6Vv6vCHM0Qi6mK8aB0EvMehvyS1cCXxSHg70fVDPoN8yQKr2j2Vcup8SJA9Hxqh7ektSgWbtJyV3QujnlfVUMuQNqHP1K8vLMW5JtjQPq4yzf50vjd@LuBrUlM0rfmb9UcjZHOzIQxpaPMwyXLeJ260WV6NxRm2ipfgG2ZAXQ//CVCXociD7HwPhW6yO6fSwd87Mijnbo8FPMZ1DrlbCPUkepK3kdOrMPYXEgngWboD6rK2bCUZw4bAUjUYiAR4J1wS7GoC5UHSWF8/58WPCFgOxYROs0mEXF2zpblhMFcV7VmZCUWD1OseKF506qw0NOoh7zKNfLEn18lIoHg8thS61IkuFPHBZhZ5xLrg0AdtR6MHzOyYB0yR@YADdbolL/Byj1aMzwjAKbMNo8kyjSV4cmfLTePyo5yluOvq7v2o7R6e7MhS2r4B2CgRBywF6X@7pt@s8XSd1aPMSHr1GHKDIqPwgYHyzyqCHhWEnPzGt37Kz7dO8cw7TMVMAL0d8WOLlglcuTnziKQqbVx7Pjbcj3knYi@UWCuT5oK/BQL9t96wEtAA6IDEwx/uRwYVgmm3ibEc7xnZZW8a9HnTuhSb4VF2/pgNsmJO/@yt@@pROvzinEtzk6dS5L0U85CLSkc9WSx9Arl0kn2RTd0DCSGRQawY4dc6wpyP/CJ4JoWOxwJFx91AoJcNPhm5WT1i8xkJogQHPmpWUTnipevzizUWqXv6O9ZPyf/pRMnLnEE74Jl7IWUKMuSCle2Qsf3AWgsehISYsDQWeoHc0SHHk9C2vDyCRxJkMTwe5PKbrhtNq6GA/nWP3uNExMBNGN9Wzezq0TzYBiGHlWzodShvnNZTSeNhes6CBwWuEUPNWV14KD/gMb/zEZllIEE/YSuDiVgTosAyedMQoS0P2mfWQyeItPMABb5yQKh6u7Zc33N1/Gf8ezeSW3BzQvqSbdCKdKVNxlhrltQq5TLmt4yH3i28vh@lU/HK4WqsnLZeol5fDb1Lpt0B13YRYz5LY8moHW3dLiUrq82dLGjFBuA@V@J5SEBNLd0e7R7WT0@rp2QnUwr0rfrZ1sy@NZQ1yER3J6OkqmQ8AupiKbH2F/PHeADwcZksSW0PDOJFIwH8mgEAdWgtxYYk7faJpIvYXos@Lb8m@8FkAR6Z1FOZy1C50A1iHwGxINSz8wEAjCMyJ6xzkJi5TUMZjA/IIgzt358hSIpXAykCsOBDriaRiDxd2nfs9hWJfxPI42dbngiDFvPQuvHBexLkkuP@dlNuAjvK3LzfH8ni5CeaRcgOo5@vG2a7u7p0d1yajAY/Rk6RuuZB1DsNw4YwtjU8OuyfX6USiExFnx8sCEygCf3U6M7J61JTtWxmK5QjHVp9HJg6l/AuBMWMCZcpoOqpe4rQIhykHqIOUsFhTZ3U6ytCXRbeP9qG740X0hMC24KF2M54QHMxBMuOTwMstBmJ1yOU2vSMS4o68Dll@9SfmtjgsGvbRMPCmWA90VV6vYzH49/VKritdZ0PmdGdincVZGn6qrHWhwC5spMT7KLbECSEs8bwLXn7RhAzkqX0l0SQVbRt1jiNBL61KBtqrcKAPdFsuso8DnU5VusLE0y9ucQpE4taSqGpbEpaGTmtqNtqecPstwre7fVJG7YyrZiTf/Tw30LCjAiCf7SIYX5loZqpDsp5bQeEk1x2DG25XSasWlnPA3tMSLHajWLSqgZXQQR1HBUmJpXEKjobD6Dwtq6oW6CRt6L65mS1SThJ0toEfcIhrTAgCTyY8lTHGhADCWuVZAwzQld6Cst/6wCMvERxhtnw4Q2uL8ThQrqtorqGrIi6@0Kx0kdnmALcIVUIzUdwsFMkV79l91Qc4xxTNpZz8/g//jJufubTB/VPHPUxtwNvvO28dcP@BGyKK8PavvLc0vP2Mv32bxCqbtbnhJO@MyR88CAJ8@VyYKRPKBNfaF5XFq22s6Te7R8yiFSKsy7409FUTShjkOUUDeil9YIobqmME5ymMq3CMJ3zxBlgE@Ar4A9Ub1GgoPdmsh9HyQjGZxIzjNFaCTg/IQ748RIYYPg7QABEoYclcNrciJiGT8RsXIZ2G7uL@dY4wEimCTAzcKEb5Q7OFx5KYYMH4WS7nSpw3kkvStxnhg5fRJYAN8IHCBYM4eJLJiwFhFSdaeEmKihGMih1ZSAyhTGvrnNVAGwyTA0Ai6K25hz5B3dQdUgEfa/LQJo1p5A6AmmhoDqe1ZW6GykUUB0QcN5rJmW6O4x3peILH10AT/moQzhHsBMGKwjxmvfiWXdqXWt0xl8SA8X45h3U1cP/LOTaUOGfh@fBZ4z3hadM7WBr2/ETT8eTCNuSWhdPJdCYp5iI@DhUcVJBfbOqfASU0bhAWLVm50g2rulnbfXl4dDJjhIYgQ9NgIRaqrEUv44nYRd1zhLx8TxJ1Yzt5sr@x7ZLSn6vx5h6EGO/wmc7mvNSmc/pA6uf8KMBs2hQwk5CYeipiWk6Pb9MGuFns49CkD3CT70SeSTUcubu/qK9VLrXgTPKf5xnmCiaWkbnAdWmRWa7QdDYxi7vuAYdTNPhpJdyTbmlhbHbOO5/H38feD5uR8cyHjm3JuEcpAnQWe3xeO/HAIQsoeyLJkyJDKjxjbn5B1rhZFTGr4wRbgZkNWv7cMKcss5ZOncOGHpEO@RySa6fS4pAWCWc@y0QGnTyaeXCnLkZs@mPrLo5Zkx7kTlWagVvnBL57VNM7fZ@wDFWxw5GA5kBMH9qchbQeNZLigUnliyHzTh9aqDMOEzS9HyYbZLf1ALcxw1xTMFGyJnM0ALod6QYbz6Jtya7rGHQqtjXg070yeznoA1yHHscy9hYyaFlxiAz0DLlZuUD7KQ4lEv12NjyMJHrysK10occJR2Igmr4RxbEdGgkNqYBe1ZxXApyWMnoSlAGrJrOGZlyGkbUCvY4LyOcT2e18b60eAGQYtRkp8pmL0JnmmgzDii@yUMyjTDMSCyUYH0k51sBokwlNRCXYZg@35NLUR6ejkMrmt@7AO/OOYvYTWCroZjgLvcAN@X6u@SqTQD7KSBdSQtHa8jCM1heKdaQT@Iduz29CEWGGxckukWOFpj1toMiVhZLtCKWxcZ8peVcoeHJuUjQUCmjBAc@xwqAEUjyxzT1wgooQ7vQlg4UHZOHJYglGr@HLsBazbDPC4hXsrm@ZxqJRmtOABwXAmAVBO@RSyJRGGA0ihpNlqCT0tbQ2Pj4pBrsQE4k6uCmRCFvC@cxN0KZwJjASgDEqRCkSWtAv4K@IOeLmaxOOGdslSjZARlYAam4wySlcyQH5ArSgUrPKM59xirGA4VQtFIpObUxK@wIDvlibIxAB7Rwp7o4RgL7OQUSgGspogNo05bYC8vL5K1nTZCAQ8EwfrfVKA2AyMxJzDUnHxoYeKYUgz@KOc7IRMjppALIWulNxgWQpWaKpsdI9qDUfLlGv6TiazSj53yYTydJdeEktj5Kga0Yq4aVeWYxmlqPRJW05vKShtvXsGc6o3S@BMtdIwAB1CEDxJTVSAn4G5a@8pJWWpLXwUrucXqYY8ApD5DuI8J2VTNwtSffJpWegLMXAx@RCJ7xkkW2mVCIh3kP@sIUsJWPAM3doZIjMQ2PyS0o0inlILDUwA98lL0@i1G1eniRp8q7kjAWS3b7T3KZUMa8mZsxacwI63kWvw8pih@XsUm24wGPzj5l5YQ@ofzzhV7iXn9EWJNnyD76EyZCnCxZHTqPMdYRMmBvHAgIOw0BEfI1JkQgIk9/8JijmGBPWc5mwHl3PpkrRUFaEYTqMr4PPQQ9PLgumcHe5Fb9hcied@xi/kDqJj/Wj66Ojt5HLMCuwUHDzUBBXhG/RgvfTrlWWfuBiP/wKBpeTgWByWXy2mkx@@PABRhxwXVQSFRAf/IpcxEP1i/AqY5XV1eVYLr8cex5q@LIVCafTkROmKEl2qRhWuw0/vUe23MNBfq2vU1ow/Id/xv2c9B2H@4Igjm/wK@FupGyQXa5K0nJ0Jf1cKyXSqfTf/c3ifezuqLH2d7/XT8qL@DjEx0/v99F9Ima/WVz8ZmNjZSUGhOTuo/dH76rV6spWLHt0kV1fiacW1/7j/7m4mE6vpZOLdcsS66GL67dCOrUiJP7uL0JHR68blgWEKOCVYSI48Z6Hn8iyWXbNPsF13WH4T@5PbZ9bQnez8wkNYsF4pUzCJhTKZkIn34bmV9siEyvrq//554cfg3awkk6em/C0gx@DuXyQO8EBbxn37SZYCa4hWO4@OEqWy2Vwrv7nfwfxKy8BD4aM1uBWybq4cqNgJV6mKJ@DlRw4xHQa0v2/f/SjQLAyDH4KiqIYHNFfA91w5Z@Jzxg6ksJqXtD152htHq@h7xqXIimK6Uu3Pn3VjVXrefcAN9Qr031@Xr17XMUcbiDHU@EqcKvh9ff/x9//8d//nP7@mH7/AY2Y5xaff9hiTIYeGK9i8flMPexNvR8n4nAlvNYRxNe4U7Jgvhxr8Fx5LBz0Oabo4N2ZQxLv/SvhAkHXEi/KoTrb18Z1cRkU8yuHzx@ooPn2k4LexZxkPJJ6ibNpP7cyvBfmygL2NXCB4Hdsn1@aBv/wc1/RBz320U/jN41DuDCeN/dBdliHaxH@6B8u7xXvi@TjeBPI7LX4W0jfQPAieFGv72j41/yIf3uf8O@jjX@nLfw7/oh/p5/w79jGvyML//ab@OevmUBwbW0tGI0eg8roMO1TrjP4JRIN581j3mAg@Du9WACaQz0av7@/SHw7jJZKzj/oUSXvDS/ughzV7@PxtW8r0egF5eyi4mRxLb5ymDtkz@sVnmu6JxrfrgH26NrF2lpZ36RfolHBK17/tnKxNomD0NQrz59Hsck@BxSV@sVFIHiHtVLG2zLeWhbe04KQpNfPKOGhyy4EgqjtFrjSW@Ae9DkOfAsEP9x9CEfXo@spNXWTEq/F6339cPx/eDiEAGWYutLNVC/VE9sgMllKPkuNUqNhqq8fim1wyvCX6oNTSXWGqW5KS2miOBpOoHr4v3@o2/uHOmDTIaY9TNmIONWBZ/fwcB/wdSDtK/hTUqnUEDI5TN3Af0pFAU6W/uj5bSNyB9eH@w@X95eBCyZ8kEFPSIihRCqUyIVCSj2bMz4KsVDj8iJULwWT1uVlkmtQLL1SIlOP9/eNRu1gq9FIIk8tRZ9H48/hKleia85jPVgprV8W41iVbqUGk2vrl5VMHN25KNRSGv2iX3mNMcKzsngZgCHh@Tn@zm9vbrmLHOi6PKerwYPPz5Pc6/bcuW7hSt48gGDCwUAZ/Sf6bx/@l/W/f8ZY@KIegfvd/VqYrgj@RSJ393f3zr0SCYedl/Aa/KEHvGOUu/sKOgnoDlwX4Ug9cn/P/eAejqxxhBVMY61CkceA0GSDPNXLUIkxGD2FnYW3y8thKhUpNcHHm4KXPtMaTqREu1uWmrjuBiMGcTlCINmVUmnFca/mS6W84xZzuVJp2YNKwYvjBCDZklolZPRS0IhgHjj7h1M48UL2dEPhttzBDyusGwaM/sRC6vNnz6vRaCtmo4H@mc@fL6ElhXBzS7mQBZ9U/vNnaIehCIwMD3RnWbUA4zwxmR6j70mWZNtmGMb@scsQ7l2zLkMRDE@nUgiM8Vl2bS23UqnkVsCdy0ciJWGJ74wJd6MFMXK/lBR4MWDMFgo6QWJ@NUK@9yEMZ8E1tl4BFrfwYnf3QaI2W8lGws2RHPE8xEKB@7CVXDgfLTh/5cUIS1aWmfN3cZGJriyvLj@v18caCEqJ0p1UFu/Ld1IR5xHuSy3HmC1uLpaePcsUgCz5VOky0GhsVU@rDfwqCK5RgxRm6EnyJoDrj4YZuqBJn2yhfoEFqV@GQsXSc16v@SwLhkoOXDwEkovlC1TeIIwslQ6eKhgCVsQbCBbF5XRmMZkdfpOrpWBEtIzXxcVFPp2PLoNcWy4U6vU6@a5RjIv@sFMng2bl@IWYy9bjqMdcDTvLQYOJq5ngcsCgnUarKdbGxVoTJ9AWwROqlDVxXd2SVdW1HXyrm2r7VmnLi4Hg0V51s3YaS68ByvR2dTOWPjnbCIr4mh2/U3AG349r1a3DM4hwtFerntRe7L6pnR2BP1oahat/JMkDuSHfDga3@N6Q6dpULOnqSjKMhgHXsPP9L3/y/S//u@9/9bPvf/WT73/1x7/@xR//BH5/Bb@f8efP/m0hi/df/@Jf/eX3f/4r8PwP8Pv38PubX//iT37Ef/T@t/D7v3x@f@v8fHD8FwBcv//rX/z8L379iz/4U/j9G@f3p7O/P/yb@b8//vHDP4z38798HOZn/w5@/xvH5cL@7M@5Hz5n4P@cw/3Bn37/R/87//@Pzh86f/X9H/0t3pyXn/zs@x///Psf/973P/7p9z/@5@nv/@R/EVP@218CJ/3jX/8S/3/@1//473@J///r//SPf/0//OPv/8/k@DPu@H/@zb/l93/4vZ/8w4//9T/83i8euP/k0fsvnuD/i38Cn6fn8yl4nlKur/X5xQ/Kz29DjXEqwAPAW//y@z/5F8Bef8Tf/nt4g38v6KfeixcSpTFoPDr2/Cljn5Og3aWef/ZAAeX/iL7gzT5PYiPflOv761/8679A7wnYf@HHkBJnYZcQ2Evtp9g@vIz5YX@KLez7X/7o@7/459//8s@@/@Xvo9CNrxRi1Vhc/MLAFACzT4BDwNxT4ABQXMNV/UW2GEiDY3ENp14CYvTDByDrIrhgoLAcyGbgLViv01jj8iJZuUxeVvhVh/dEsoI@ieRlEsMTSRhnNNg3MEbD3/Pny@ybeJw/x34BsUKoIY9R6HtEGNAt85mUKI7P4TcMrBTgDedWotBlRnlQFII2oqxcLkcDwzKEESi8Ypwhq@RxpI9jwzLgxUg8TqyRBy2cDTcIC8QsR49ZY7k85BGj6FEhDAwzhF7HgpgWovnyFiRYHm4xxIXIo4EP8PxQruTLwwqi@46yADiiG5AkQJUxd8PKd/BeJpwAHxhufQdZyZej0UoefMpUVEot1qA0xSwVjsoeZVRu9IcRPDzWnzP2jSDmBT54hZphDjTeo2PodZrDWYfwy@iyUxz6d530W8b4UO1Dog/34@Hr6E3xHQDAG4/jhjL4QTUCwHMIHnJUUUoWHlGOASgXdaZYPA9SWKKBKNVvlF4gfcjD0661iu8F0WFxlpaWwLVWETLCIYx9mHldtGzJxPUW0umKTMgVBPTG/Tny0hGNjpa3luEuwn9tkfbYcnIsB5ZCqL@EmJtGPJrRV/Qg5d4tGpVlmXIeJbhAcOzP9XFaNANFeoVFAmH6AkCEhtiyYcBz3@pu6EPQmWOCEBNzfFo84ozA3@nFYvk7cWU1AE96H@DHBxwz@FAN@EG6BDZWJGjlLr5GDRecoGPlApWKs/DHxEDlpHYKEU4PmZhOJRgo2ncrq@mV7Eo2ncnlsqtpcSVXWMll8xkQerlUNp0WCysrhXxh9Z6y9BwER6y43MyuVf7ZzPXf/LN513xfvAKVt2yYYPH7QGUYjyfTlOOymF0tjcqQD/IKVEh75EOK0V0c93sGLml/2R1uZYJsBe7iyKYLcLHAQoAtgBdcgBaXPJizDr97WHIWJPGzLnxRUhCzwAiRwCUwAscWMKavAFbcM5A2z0TuzObGzhQ6T/Gc4QGkAdWgsT3c/Gnr7FTnmww35FZgzTkhVwkEaAXnAohaD@B3Ey7qgbWkFzof02aPf@1w09RBJ//hMBuSds2DthR@NsoL2pHQeJnVV@zeAxBnRh8P58jmPxmGWr8JGcSZWg6wATdT1fV5AKvs7OiBUu5755ZxKZQOLgP48e6LnVPf87RW3dwJ5NjG4cHW1CPrAGXZXm371Htd5aFu1KyH4l1tb2/61XnguGqRZVdjMZCPcMNnjC56Jpa@dUHExCNTztA5JdfYUofh0DkLbZ7lQAJflivSsKMNgMVhYJhsyKxR3rgQS8F6Jb@yml3NpQqr7PnBoD9ASrDuIL97yFDgvRUyq0JRWBfEgrjOzoqLJfPOvpdigX3cG1cQ@RkPxQrswMCsj19FQIsadsCU2zBIu9Xo@EoTv202MNiDnvBAL3SaSrcHwu9WdwECTUli8PvaC@LL/st@3MPmaZDfTIg6BxxXA5UOSwUSNH@XLuSz@UImnY/lC/mVLIxfszExHRNX86uFVExMiXkxl88WxFh@pZBZATEJodnCaiAI4kTpJJPQC4iCQE9Fa6Hl4jU0Aa0nepVAkE9/QNcblqCPj7CgFGx4voM8EzL5yxREFvDbEpZNW4CXlbKAH8hN4ednAbXEWiy4vb2Z2t4WhA18wYnLzZQgtPElm0@lVjcEQaaQTZDpaUHQeRwIAjCbv6RSG5uCMOAI8Bi2IPTwpZZDfVYQFHzZrG5vYzpX@JLG@AB2zUP4i@q@rAKYhi@ZDCnEgvDRQwdwVZ7QCuW0hi@YJoZs85BNCBOEF25@UinAcMzhOIYdt6zVqiDs8pdqFUNeUsGzPKuv8KVKlyCY8ALcKAhdcHRNWdYEoQlO5ElBaIGrNZLAD@1F44ldzZYEYcQJhCQShCFBS61rATQtxx@T2dnZkXp2W@7ya2TyZwuyBiHKcFDbbr540ex2m@aoWntxjCEvX@5IV6OB2ew2nWjNBlw6xIGQ6/5o@oI87jYakjo35BWEaFMhjVFDxrw1pI@QJ@fqYiL9xksIeQkhwzkXxwZXH0CbeG304bkhNSnEvSiEnsNmUygho9ojQ8YJI2w8tJMq1pdapl7C92F5MRQOxUYX6XqJfFk/HLlLle4xsBOmL92glIzcjS6G5VQdlG@xhPNW4cU@SqqsUFyU1sNDdOdAeonpFSFSXFwehi9jjci6kAb1t4ifDNI7IRaKi@uDvJADMbcMTxB1KPGG4VQoxRjcYpGL1fq6sIpIhfX1uHAh4ivASPEVTAHl4yqqBqV7oIUNHVVzYMuNRjh8K0vXkQhmF7UJyvf5@Xnkju8cG1FZlVInPIwNyzw7bBQpYWFM2R5AP5WaQdnGk8qDlq2bHHEXCDNcTxWp9JCZvADZSCYjayieUKDA88P5uW9m3puh97n4lWDFOP8Wj5jPRRK4I72hdxr0VQz2wQeIyuM5nhuhM6PuBiPSm61i4BQ1TPqSJ0PzB038@BUd04WhC7fDQp@qkkHfLAQCFUflwpPMie2BhkVL4Oe47JITcioP7cSOjNuAWq7fJj@dmagN8YuViq65AScj0Br6id3DxJlmSR25dBc/j9/TUWE854knt5U2k8oVcEntMCXEpMgt5blRqZQb5b7cN@wRjFBISa54caF3ZBuMQ@KJEXfTPPSkUJRUSUM7JdSxLg2Dw0CljWezN8obd4NiEWDvS3JZNk3dFIJCqbOulQeUwSPZxPMdu4fQZct4kKLV@3BZQ7hNoNrdfbxiMq3ULV9gup/xthYXhHo8fvG5DqpwOVUaBaWyNWiSJQyWaoKunisNwU9cXSmpUFR@SGaJtspJpR5rlpvfDktm2RiYconAP6vQnzUSDWhHF@lUIZYWoceCngyC4LcK7yvwE@GXht9qfXGRhdVwaphKiDFRFmO2XtOAOKliEWkExKVXeEqRaHpZDbd1Jq3FidbQeEqYMDTgHjOUWC8MsY5lSeXgkejH9VycrYiRUngxUrbkjyU//cORUqcc/jZS@ghkNpfC7cRGZH2l1A5vsEYEPKA7hl@a5Vb4UIAKZiw2yik@KFiyBv2L1GJOjN3FG/F7VbLsJXE1XbwYLF3ERShX6nN3TXhfEepA4PsAjB/8c@nQl5fAz21WvPcf999jP6MEqpoqQ3WIhXTJAQkYThsPCyyMn5fjG8bCodBqOhSKhEoAtQjeJCoid9SgQyBvQs9EkDLQsxaFQhrCx6JhJgd84JMTA8H7QFuxDLZSCATvAvd392sVV0N8xUYjKRp3X58x1o3CEDhJi3@JRpAtkiueqDxn1XK1e1wtOaDVTRqoJgPskh9DjCcXv3aJMbpW@ZY/L3F5GZIJcOLQenxyLVpJXgYEAZuIszQUzmcjfID8XZAMvLLNuw6KCWj0xX2klVQ8oe8uXNQj3x0o6l0@E6/QyAm45f4@GIWy4U6TSpIo1TqkDR6BoKY7TlwtsEHGgPjMZgUcR8vMOCl8u/pt/tv9s8Ozw232PFXMF/OcDJd8aBsTQ2JojT0HLU45rgWCxmc9K36nvSwFi0YosxLKTOjll2XnAH4YeSB8gUtp8KtfwAC5HgFXuSyui6tFxXJWusJFa2DIZmRdzKWL6ZQYCVr3eDo4vRqkp5hbDdaDHOXKagTctEaTFoOVpOMtrmKsOH8D5s0GrcLnYDqVDwTz@x8@M@Z@D1tJkyuZdDK7dL92D/@V@4u1NXZP8wP39I@3JNzuOQD9YwT3hR7jawJuDDMOr38XX@P/a3TbPOQ5F3JQD8EPIBAs69vGt41gIFgIwbgmxNJZJ49DZ8SNuviyRn@ytYx/3449li3LWvbe4HUZysyyFRgQLSeTycvI6zTo7YVCTkwHA7@ZvZLLCwG2vFBlIW5CjXd0aEDVO4EWmvhCHU7qLC/Et04ON1/VTrGnkzX8wjDbPDxIYBB@BHd8hLClypKpjpyv4I4QCjvI080jppvsbOuI4pzT4VHypbkbJ5Wl3XbR@VRU7IaJiQyuX2aTqZWkmGVivphaLaZzTAIxZKGxCMe1hFEZFWtTN0Z8tBXejFDkhSrCYNieAmNhSy6yF0d7FIPsSCwvbNX2D9nhwd67hOvL/U93dk/YyeH26Xn1uAbl2K@dMKF6wnZPBHa@e7pzeHbKqgfvGAQfVw9Od2sniCAZQBGGWiAnmDf0YWvWyEqiimjR@GfC29Jb17I96S@ZhpREi8CT3hp@H0jGr2pM@g80BQZX/qHVSXWBK1YM0UvtthnAU6tKiy3gYGphGbpuPDTbS1mrLDt4@yllZhdZa@UgtMpaqQMts7bK1JTzx9SVfuaYLS4uXmqCJ//9xfBGdn4vPO8AfuM87b6vLYRzK2wZRnHplcg45ODwaCHlvi2cH58uiF7Y8dZC2nvZ3V7IeC81eFvx3rbPtxay3ttG9dVCbhztYHNh1Xvbqm0u5L03YNKFwhjnwdaCmAq4xLoB7WqBvoEY3t7dq7FlAIqUJkJxRg0dU95AiDBoRNyECJKcLS/f9vQYDRCaoynotvwlaBd8AmoBdbILpGs9xpZ1A26g7QEwRAt4OrpkdlsxBytaz4KOJXAXWMACLWCBAH4BD68jHFsss3SEQfBCh2@lCHNrijEmnFl0RPUbi62hDl0BZoiROS46qgwxZOdjqIGFewdluEOzjh3af02gIuRUMIVIBM83Hpzt7fHEDFIlwwJBMq5XzsGpG4ANigh3LDr48srh1UJ1gbRacJQK/GBr4H6iNgPTtYmkgHIuLLQAwSR1byQ1xlCpiuE6PeLFF35uAoAhGNwpcPGDneFwC8vale0WZSiCxKwdbvMS4kp/mU3WcoRhokQpCuYnMj5/Zu7bpT35ak6@aiGO20HOs8Xx8ZyWETaCfgvuiVqCIOsBFHMBOSYahdhQHArzlWsBiA4/bmzAzWUFEkqF2LNnlI81eCuEKAmMF6UUWRxBEIFDMCIfIvOytkjZjSwkl3EPDu3IIYuv2I9wA73NkWcoBSTrdEanatVrhV51LmgwtCxNCWQnqNPGugZ3Jt2AdxSPwMkx1oRmEmNuoJjDQByGxZgcYx3wnpKpDUUDzpXNsUx0WQEaI9X@wRavIW4ViPy5B5UY5F6RKgyExTNsvsToCwtNE0baJRcK5CFBAd8i04SREBzu8XjHWxRtmbcXZEuM/ZSYu9tFl494bGAHh9OIrGjIgfOKU1zyrIyBZvA7yLD9lgE9Z0mOLBp1IDwuc8Bqk3DxOIe7d/nyC4WoTZdi8atLgWL5wVLUnliM364U0K2NWQRKASI@DHijAE23ydpMz0MBfSGhoNL8MBTQgY55Cdr4BIInxIcudxw//vXxoZMuTjdlaLdQg1wq8CiTr63J1/bkKzZf8JEYjAnSK@wza6JLzIELD/SzPDjaXFZORuxMvtIsTZnJbpyOJ4F5CsBzKCo5GDLgrDBGCZKw8GMiUh8/aVVm1e3G7kHtdDIU8SWshpPxnq1rKqURmQRzMoThVhhfIl6Owh0kAtc3w0c8jRjRs3Fyelyr7scgfxG2Nm4B0zoA3JyWMFGCezcF8NXkFvTH7RgLn1TZcoQ9w5zFmDNXgC9PTkLVLRlQPZhie2CkKakUB/HeJ1tSEFtkYE5SQpiFI@zz5SV0qalVJvaNz5l@RlvNtNkos4rKLsfj6SCOlHcFzAFvmlzZQMg2txxZnJvYVSrFVswMs@UeaNzDlDmLn8p1j30bdYvusWNDp0GZVWJ4yhtli2OkBfrFSdXmcS2S@kbkA/TFZgx@2J3TzF6U9HNkTwp1FSyel7b8tXn5kkY7mZc4z8saJTqbh984s6EwXApMHS0nWze6YRsSnr52Ag9pDvUIvcxAgE@z@EyehXX8jJAdKZKpGpQpjQaajG00wpasdoBZ9YHZgi4f1WXLAcMLQxM8kBoSOiYDHfKg/jQZ0FbwtDQa5IReZwohGiMBbzSwGKYUAwEvZ5YtG5QrXzZwmgy/r@1PEAbYE@9QrXiK0ZfjSNHRirclbA8usosJK1Ucx8DqxeZ4g3ie9fXYdE6YxzZzwtAY4bwo7un6OWFXg/68HIBgeCDEOR87J0TTD@dF4EaexgH1Cx8BL/wErtfDkflVD@1qssZ9VrqI/qfmQHZMTu0e@lgQlEuHA311HdySgWlbCn6cYRqRd0IfYoaHEZ@xAI@tImNOkqyWokyjdzE5iOi0K31/gA2LrR5g/UZM5yMxH0IfxjY3UPsQTuZDCjmcgyTIToj33QlQy0ONLDiNdxw/gbYutDYM78YRdOMReAwdw2Llu8ALaKbMC/GYeU6TG6MrzjIO@eOcO1a/OGHQ7SFotxBixE/Q3zb5@NcmH/elj23yByVdZheT@ahHfe9F8BiX0W3gPyghN9eTqUW@qsR@rpHl6wfYFw3v@JLhBjcmk/XQOBLI4ym3KIQePZ4oJBCXH9FXyBeqPsccwLzY4/5nuczioheHS7xxa6DJdV/mA2gqpNFAG7uNBhlXbDRwZqnREHgK1PFih@fvdJ3GxsMSoKU2dAoNC3FJiAnxePVkc3c3rmhCjNu7LwuWrZtyA22kCTFcFS4LJLAaCNOTVaMsOBv5JItRbOHhNKq@NKCAX06EgHgquxolMjae@@XkWv4i6U8okj6V2Nig5xNSO6bU0HbBYymZ3DKem9AmGW9Da3imrKCg4Zb8nY/To5WTCeMaOKXvZIGna9FMn4UmTXiW6NFAP6eu0TbInkKjaprtE1xjP8KMbR6nteNUDyIYcyrnPuGIvvfFyPBbW3b0LJoeSghjo59OxhJOSX387ipo3FbKuEObNADk5Dfmzk1aOI05ldWxYNENLPyFgPaBoAKOdAPuno0gcHtWgsCNdoLQyxV14EYjQRij4zgce0HgIotB8AT2FsYGSvvSUOkPcOLGb4XC0eTG2cIuH0tCvT4FTko/TlGESKho6Tns4I1EhaIARbfIOtG0hSKEn2ekKFIPzApZMqmN2fSpDvOQzjV7FIn9DirJp4ihaLac3EDcmMAEroRQXLFYh8Gnj3dcEYPq85Sfzmc9ERGUJObFH/dXPiNH5YnhBVIEBg88M@MIfJbJ/11NUu4jRU8FGdeYH4orbnPyjftwH8y4H4OrqEUCj4yk/n8zTvJXyX@hQ6X/7wdFM0Off@KhzCNDmK8erfwOhwX/VaH/rwr9D1Dof2fa/AMq@TTK2RY/pa5/UQ3/evWLZN4Iug2ze4NTb@kfoof9jhSB1a/SA9xcX4iP6QJf7p9dNGl/t/4De@nAb5Kn7dz5tl6tVk/7onn8otqt9qrHaE9qI7UXPb9a2di63Xix0a5ubXVfdjcP5Nf56sqe8ept/t2LzqePMmjvO4cv339SjVYv8PbYuD2Xj24zct6qDgYfd3dG9s7GWX/zJPtu9TZVU7OdDfnjlmpt7Z@@fXX6InsSvf348ujlp36qbx11UlKhn9nZz73ZHJ1rgeyNctbe3lMO@yft2lm6v7elvNuObqb2TgqvxdRe7fZ9ZvM2mk0ld41Xhy@Oz66atffq8e7eu/bmR13Kfby@NXaT7UJn8@r4TeAw81rc@Xh42K2lCy92krdbHaOdSu@oZvbq7fHRxtm7nd4rqdbfzp4V3l6NjnK9169v7INod@U8N9i3VqJa9fXr9Cvtxc1N7TjQlPRTMyOf669F4/b2SC/0V@VXBzvd/mtT1JKH2TfRk/7p7VZtQ/24OsycvTt/fbty8m6w//rl@8OUcnLSrEk5o9lOn1ydrgRa/cxu9OasdpaXXrTPX/dvdney77aS@z35oNo@Uq9fdHfe6ydHe7vVjDXQxL3NG/Xdi97V/vXW5q6qH12rWnUlmVVP2@8ODwNnL5Xmlrzz1npZveq9S2Y3rlfeRdvGi9OrT73rlxsnZ4f59PBolNI3rePmTme4dZxL55Mt9ePxp46@L569juZurl6mlXfVT3Yg82mULeyp7@S@9jLa6r4fflST0TNR3Hy/@@ndu5OdG7NZ1c4@vtk@vjL329qhdZg6fvlqv6le5@0r4712ciK2Ui/k6/1oSgoMz3YsqCP5VMqunvb3XhvDLf3j8e57K/cpenN@nZG3ro/fVD8ep5q3mvFWM/eU/maqfShV3@h2bTB80SrcnF3vqHsfD613gf2amM1u6x1ro/NmpfA2@SLauX7xdkM8GaYOtOPOSs48ePP6XFFqvbdnn45b2e03Rr5va93Xn876tWhtb9j7JOdTTfXk3bUWOMueHB@lb7VXSt/e3jnez9mHqb03R@2dkVh9LYu32urmKLs1NHOZ86235rvrHc1IvlM@Do5S8k20/c6wV14rzU7rjdLqvwqcvOydHRy9ud3N5swXfU3ZOMqnDvZ2Ng@67ZVXo939QW2vedV@sftWfmuc5q7TtY3z3Nbbk4x9ev3KLrRu@pmjfPRU7dvds2jg5aA3WD06Nz@@Gb5fqfabcuZYfaePVsX@5ksjPXxTrR1@6l4fGfqBuJ0eJc/29Gs19en09tOOlauOovnhmd3X7VNxmBVfBzK3nwz7pfHy9cnhxsvD9y@lFUU5l65O3rRTmbN8UumZmd1c7oVY2@70P/YLsvhpaz8jZfq9qLV3nWxvts/enF@rV/1X/atWIF@wWhu77weSXmumxdS7jU4tK@9t7J2K8ln31cnK1kHq6G376Ozj8LS9@XZw9uZQSdWuXhb2uitvj98UXq2@P7VOpXP97SvzIDDMZ3RLzBWyt5mTQv6wZ55kzq8K9vtXV7kN9bwpvtxN9@VtxXybH@WvjU@92@7tiZxqdl9sfZSOOzWQpGdHKSk7uD4YngQyb077N6vGRvTddevVW01U8@fKavL041Xhutd7dbvVWjmvfvooZV9cyYWT7WRT3c6@iB5vvj666m6df8qvtFMbe2@kt8Naz34XeL2jbF0Vzq8PhyPx9fbJqF9NaWr25uQ8e3Oqb5yc75zke/tNs9PcueqBbOiPzq5uBzc78mpveJt/1bt6I6X23uY3NWvlKBV4Ke/228enr95Wo520XLBvDt8dGOf582F2P6@fF/TDvPKq2nkxfH3YqaVWDeX8dHhW6yU3NpV@HmTKkXpmbh6@3nl//tJIBdJabuPTpp5d/Ri9Gb7LnSePonuDd63TdP/cNHfeKub225ujt69OqrvR3eboxdG1dPiulj052Ny0Xka3lZw82sncWtXNjNrRA1Z/Y3gwNI1C5v31Xhd6Ar1daL84zZxrVrXaud3Nn9Sq1RdWc/elNBy@6KxCH4FX7fyNXg78htsKDHAzgfwhcTskgb7VbepDkJf8XGCADncF6HBXgB/noh3SfPfxb5LLgVP/UQb6KjSf4Bk0QVljbR2VhwTb9Qz64vc8YqyvQ3QFXS3doCeidc5rtHHAp8Kd5qvw5CF901IeGqqu4KeS8LMNOCY1x5@fSwQONdYf4XjTlvv8gIWCXzty7O/Slx74R6XI/mdgodVi7pc/E2Rd1vsO6AdQIAytGydzwl0Wj7c6qtS1wKG2yfUhcOKZu8cUVEXCyQ9MQtxrSGIq62xNpa/1YeZO8SNNBy@YqvPvSLgjDgmUiRHZYcFJKrLFIuPXAS3lRlZH9GEQuZ0I8B2fT9oF6ffD3d2TfmQDdWpvKKgbsjm1AdTgEd2V1uTyczSR83w56SyxojLUkMymYuO3pxv8qESDp@jueTMm9x7SkWBngZYrRqjZkPVg7uxLQ3ybioUUo13m4xN6uJ8OUgQV1d1tuLxsEErad8X4iw/zsvEwbqXf/V2hnsDdVuQJvDrQagC0ogXpmTX7byza5OgBlQJ8sb72dve04Xw9hm8xnDgV9cCOSx@VS@6bUeIl8OXfyfnstkzcYQDZx2lHbnwbinqjc14WaN8jbo@E2sYR9ni3ZQK4hnYaIDaDdqNcrNT5DsIUbd1zCe7FecY54ZkvV8/GBF1wNlR4PPDEeHyDJgeZLS8i7piyTAC0m9M9GTK12e93zHsP1ExTlbRrdJX4VlkYL5gtX2XRdzF85cCpLK8szv5JfiAOyg1RvW2w44wKplctBOBsiHWr@UzD5kz77TEOr2EvaZwfwzS8UZeq6q3wOHjZ3XLDyxZxU@LwU0kd4kxiB3fW6uaIJ4TTM@FSCUBwnw7JBFlzd6v6Sl0eUwPR0aYeXy6Ab0uuF9ofkMf5jLHHc8uTWiR2oB1A87PKNwMh1IWXrTpP6mFZCPSO@AszEXVMHHcLETiTy8zWDSBCx@E46MaIR/ju1Bmq8J1eHhcxTqeLVB3@2br/pcg37mKDknHaE0VIBJsxjtCnMudlGkErXtPBpMasRxWFO7ixChXiRabACB/9mRKNTtSTD/mFgnQTWZSoHZ4TCmLIK5FDeof2BEN74qA2@FZc1uE7uDitA1MkWoOEPn/2Ggy8etx45J7ABJbwvnSPDM45k7dlh6Al991thJ6bQsZE8aTq/exeejp5CgNw/dZQhrIaBoHZwK/iGAy8nC1LhsEdBOFtXwJvrGzKuyOvFhfDEOuC4JL5OnvGwuLaWng1Hiavb/KRiNcYnehpX3RfZBDSlQoLp5fDGTfyCkYGlJlJBCvzEaQ5gpXlsOgiSDsIxCxg4CoGIfmG5TnXTiLO@xB7eOuTMPhtnTmpL6ejYn1tLY97PH2eU5HT87O@nImmITJHvRCdDOFoeYDPvz5ZIkCeSfv6ER@KlWgGUPCko5MB41SnArxE/Wmu1Od2Tr8z5cU9p@F2PhQdP/Epmxd5LC9yKt@UbjBwG7bpeOJn1gz62NrYj7P0MrI56AjUJCG1noyHpmL8Y3tOpwX0K031ir7DEQSBYoCI4OJRYuzqsb6u@fWdHQJ3aIKPlznGxBjLwzAEJApIjDxEBhFCNFC6jVbf8OCgK85H@I5v3oFRIge44oznB6CeUO13UyIxxsmHK9yAz/nYGfUhnL5hiNDY293Ax5vaMe6Y3T14AVW4gOWIsfHdLeYix@gVcVPS@AdYFFuBLIBs4wMap6y8qibTR083fQebi9yBn8bOI1LpEILxyI52SHyh2A1Fd7BxUrp8JNtER/oemAeQj5RgnMFuZSapSI4R/45xnn82jA69UWwiFTi8iE4GkUJIs9Pj6sHJ9uHxPlHuqFHdO9qpImYYYLYks83owzbYQDRNVnmn6tEzgN1vFz@ijmWSmu5XWPjn5RGWfyGREw8AGxTSIN/pHGF5OdPPwHPveRFIonjQoFQ02rIxBzfuXfXAnMJYcxDyWuS5drpCJ0/zekLq8GZ7QleOVlDSES112dJCNjA2fehH0rg8Sbr4NmCUSV9JpJaLelSX@MXkn4XLpOlb0chH1sDA1WG5LfjJL7VaskUmD8bUB5Sy2qFEHMniIxT4zC/9WH7wsyle3@vgoE9lUqeb8vTesZo7qSyC9shp94N0XJ@CxLG4OtKdq1aSWuSkzD9dPaE6KpMq40OJ8dSueGpXkBoXuOxqWiFT6hdXE4rYPPIoLnmuuG7samZcPfG2klPNdaDRWz20SkRzIVzqUIVhNZEJDn00IeueuVX2zG3F45Y4X7l7XClzCDupkTkdzrj/dAbM7TaQLTwzt0EnV2j0NTCx/vmLJt/iC/WU/KCTO8QgeOKUBqjTLpwrPvEM1YOcgZhAGtJpmQsnuTp1Kh6@sIOQxd38RHy6Bp3CdGYFFA2kxfhwmlNWUiV1yxko@jxRrDq9sNl2GzlBjjszsz19oAuB0JcfOByfSuDH@HhCeXTSZzbLhBo5ZKyzUgDXVeNxiBDh8xqk04C4xTJQ9hR7fjHys8VwCufqZAo/AYOiznGLXBQg6GcY94Cvm3hpbrl95XAPw2HkiK9gqZJzgsI90Xt2xDJiJuM7/nt4fsByufHpYDR1xlbSqfGRYzR6xnKFwA@aJxvPJ3B@xIbjVCiyFfIMDt1BF5RVFRoxf7QV7Poxb3xYPOSPUclTrpb5CNZyxLHTNVisP7BwihI/VI/rtTYTh2IisABCkeaAnS@Aup03AHYHkilptszPWKIgd1Z2MUGKiDqsbEK5mtAycNsYSnz8fj10C6bMJ4DBp623aJMk4qB4UNODPu1GiqHCcCObaAZAsZ2D/gskcxx24KKhwpnA9XSFQ8XlDU5CRyRQi8ZJFk5G6paRenzqxXGlSV053UtRLk/3ROrS3I8JYwaIvA6rEI25O7DgEHimm6Hx@LLzRTW3SXrAY9E/b2pwtpPhg1N3HO6g4X3M7Mhfqc@ZjCHuavn7oKGziYlQUZnqEfcMHEkA9whUy52H4ED0GNapeyJcfDSKFITxS1vhc@GMZARpEdRLUZdiItfhLh3H2B0FL3ifUyd@LkPrizg7A0bOgTnveKQDgSwf4RDO2chpCGyfHGLoxwG54A11OTnefzBEHN55NxTfxCHuKBzdEWdcgAj4uJbULp5/fiZtfimcNkqJ8iNp0zmloIivLc8H40V2wLB0PjDIFMkjt1Au2NnR@NybC0i5pwmpxzI/kdpTM@8kNwM0QYknZt0jxL0zVzcPKUTu6zcyX6RyttU4aqavfriSBJXoMALxLLV7Z6rCoYErFXjumr4YXGd247iShEKcQ7@zIseB8hzLafc4sCvQvWnO8bneeQXlnOwW1S0m1SB90lxVDOoaJ8vqNAt/WePibGFXfYV1TxlPFNaJ5JZz1r6DBo6Oqt9y@wvYoQjOyWXhm3aMfdPGxRDHx99HudSYJ/8mzzr7GuS35XGL9Mrn5ZUOzXovvK06a4co2v38jvEQb8pt5PhNa@oCRATXtZK7uZ7HWlhw1BlQeibipSPOtLPHzi6KTgfkNW3VR@O2e2kX05hjCEuZfcfxUBf0STYngF2wzyTnMQMRD7ajQEl9sD4uciTzRCN1uQMDolGnPytPzAaPD1A/yIh@LI7s9B1RfjQ@yZTZXIwwjHeT83G4UZzuftz@S/6MjB7MCJKD1oicvs5bM@ImEe5/25XRse5mOJob6F1GGm4fHUXM0d@yKVcPCBtjfcEbHfDxgF83cBRtVxnEiS1Q4GFszI9Gxxik/iD82MLIR77Ah0fzICZZAPFHI1MTfoHEc5j2DYsM3yBmNptUO0RRg9fJZL6pImkixMPOi/HMuEBkyXQclwG5MyrOlGoCHaNDzjQbV@LGP0iVRcPkNE71W//Ail/GwuOS5XicZeDhYHe3A6FQ@oYq85M74l6jerjrmbZiPds2ismkbOnoZSV0s5u8Va6VJAcMnDhmq@LyANs5GqniIY3aGXRlaHDKTrATmW9WQL0X1bIPNJyUB5EPGAktYGkA3OmAxqu1ZPyQi32L@wccBFbCn1kIlizQw3WNjXS9Oc695JzM4RmIUd4tyHwXCDNoJiADyZZkW/JITmLEZFOFW19CE9NJGJInsYTJQ03eg9gn0CTkxJV0IwW2fBmjk9NTqZIVukAc544oxMZvoNPuEZxDsHFfJGvqUDfe/lRnkEBWJHVNHTENTQB0AdMNQoNUgaSQ826hmLTj1lnUoS0PMo0jVlKFHAl7y@nhKB7234kEhGUjAf793iKe77B0ZBdTpr2pFH1iT8vUngzeMCc3UfBx/qRfC41zfXmfhrfFI5n0xdW1p@z7mLfHg@x/Adkf2vmRTOL0qKFKIybcSmTcm22urKZyRRxrKV2N2BBbCxrR8Wns8tDAr@DixgDsx924qnwjqyyD1fhGsQYAeGIPoEiBoGFK3b7kAoYzRYbJ@Gx00fh64kT/OEjX1UmfDp6bYOMRNZ5MY0wcY6MTXE6vgsR0vJ1@QY6A1ILbOm551nWDFcHRlpuDLnUGeC7LjYGno6RYEyNIkUq4GVmHZxGekHUyGw3tGBt/2bNfhfuJdIVdQDOvM3eBQigFqBTQ9Ms89yU3PvYcCOZb0YEOm69qQI@wzBrOYJTPEgA09mFhDmfxeU9aPHdB2vruIc7aUIJ8c7EbgkU0HFuPD@4pWWa@PSUgEtDeFDImmcBKJt2ZkVAVv2fsvmyEeCjNGoW5ezxFxHu9ZY8c7v6FDt99skY2wRjZ8CRyRkrurnqxxO5dQNwDghoO7iyJh9ydA6hhmrg2M96RAqQX3FHYY2h9Gch8AZIqDtkM@yVfMfgG7zqf7XJUkOlgse6uYYF/OVVyqcE/f@7V/3gx6xmvzQUq@CJ9TP2OOeq00OILMbRK4iwwTeQVOy@HR4g7OC6niw9zfiCPSW5wZhNp0jTmTajyjPI5VxAWqHPGqUuJsSHr4uw7Hz7F2Mh5RYP1AW6VOhUblcWSZ7pa1gb9OxyMxHiUgRFD4Hsmg7QvBfDujOhMnrjXuqGXILGOgjxAggK9Llx/nNq4S8WYeF@ilFv0WTMu4kGPmOX9uXuxLjXEV7yAoQj913k3UfymLcR4erhkQA7RdaTrsXFqnIherocj/To8jI1AdDA8j1RxRh3odibn6XXkCyIbJc46jSNgcB62IeG6YwNpF3YtkLHGsAwDpMaojHN43P4XKry8WZABGYQvMgCMxxEQRqjMVXYpnMgMom8YjWI4DOomwwdGEUfZbvyZcKw9ws/j@/Hfj43kER0aw1hjFHH3pUCMxmiZSOBtT7mfKS5l77co70x@p8o7Qw@vvA/QwyvvLD1/UHm9GeO3VBDoYuiBYxwcsq/DiBqgPU8@T7HO0DM17qG23k3HHhj4JaKp2PQhidnYumHoFtown58DnuacTFC4zx/SXOdpFMENA@Qknz4S8yloevhJACvAm7ipo74YJjd@npL3X6BPqnxu2@mjyQMxF2hG33uNT71DAhGnK/F7uSLRKx8mxWUqVydAbbum/cVl5kuq5GWcCsrHYIwie6WPMP7qw@ErOm1fhNy4UZBQETYvygD1Dow3HQX95kdxqO7Ix8lYSHU2N5ZbiRjb2V3pakIkdoRdPkoaa92Cb62pQdIZ2NWnT3jjWG@@dxh1GZxXBs30hqJuLw1Dsd0OzbZt8o3Y7MiZncJjT6DC2z1TH3R7DA1FoQ6IsHxLeUdH7R61S9Dq8ZukA7RVU3S3xYXHxffmj5PszGAwyKfz89hy94/YJir@zRHOJfO5gLCvm3B2WC0suLrTwnhKe4EkvQdc5xN9fMZhnDzVmS8DW8gPkIV9nImD5I@JneYk7HZicdHTQATJttGoPmrWCi8CFn8czcBlmHFE1ABcG1@krCx4oPMzy9nYl1vKnT@7e8Aq83KbmptJOoY6ncmmjFN9qUcyx2cRp@duIDuYOuZmS/4nqD8vVb56DeP@L7AmJOpyZYzgZBjk4uZoUHbwaF4fDZCjZQ3OqTACB5QHuoljw1FsLuZbnI@j1iXdwtiLhsoIF0042enBePYGNxrNjU0rbj0JqoqODiAiyAGpVnztDNfL8KtvGHufhqNeZD4AtkiVQ7uzPBt6C1eZ3cizlDD1liy3LVRZJeQVymcYjzc4zdVdJWwrUhdHiDBSd0Wvmx2aj6bR4v/b3rctx5FcBz6zvyLZ4ExXo@8gyAHRLAxIAtRglyS4IKiRAsRAfakGimx0tbqqie4BoVjvfWM3HGFblm2tL7G7lnfDft11@BKx@@D30T/4C/wH8rllVlZ1FQBSo1HYMVRo0JV58uTtZObJk@dy4vfYKuPRc2zKxPvh1J/wZRtbU4e5JL0fIIVHJ17vDcFijKMYe80f1WDYRlEtGKjwh9POBEUOwURVSmFB9ng@afZEEyfNR8kG1U4AE@W5i0yIBYzsJ7qCTJGVltehqEbveaSsg6E4SqEEwhCZEY6tLftBqUldwX5lBDJwPA/FQtcPCY91/a6qwXSIe3EwrmMe7oTJztpfyFh2b7rsxDDRTesjAcQbazLXwihqKBODwaFjXE5i3mmuBr@3AI1V5QDXGNrcsazxNYMGQ5kYt8TzDhkFxfILyCb5uYP0FmqYAepaTDy5QmCZZrlKlSyipaN4EesoGNVszAy2iBjgEKx83flzv6H5U8gAjXDvgQ0Gzd9RwtjroLCSmi63T1jp1EskZOkK7AOn02HUGXnBNBzOf9WEULhBwTyFd4akOX1@Xz6T7Dhew/h21sBgAGqnsUvqbqibgBd12LxXnqxjTnFfthqcuNNAzlk1FDOYsKqj8@AzkbOPeU8kDw9HrROQykGXCSjpQTWBiGy8qqw2AFsnmYuNojqV0wp2nV40pU30JEDlCtQpnaI8CHU8JmgiRlOCGzb2BZEHY2/ClQG1zYOp0ucz0Gvs6hM2yNjXpg@VytFH@HFvxm4h3fNBAngQt4UKVQ6PPasMbL/QcAAn2RG0Wx9vXU9kFHi48esWhurEGqha@Iu4fbaBiyv84Nr4FQ5lvlgl4k6Va6JbAVhslpSM9eydm3K/L@uLfkr/iVhmLevSsExQotuPLwmkVbEoltMXWL9NihaO76Kmxn20sIB1CaAH/uFNF99aWGuDZGc4i2dAIF5n0juBLsF8@Ugw0YTGqe/3adjgDodib@PKPFSAHkMYlZmBHk1Pu@iSZkDjZcw06d0DheQA4sSoy1RzbHrp0w7nV4CeX6GqJ8mP@2Wztrgqupfg5QcAjRwJT1BpE8kvZWDwO9ZsMqMzcOQTRSErOCz4fSCJ6KZE/NEvZK0cas/15sq30k5jbF2CsRwLz1ImYSjwiiwVp7Ng8oZfjlDsRjt/1PFJ7o1vgaywjIW0RA8f@cM4j18ytHAuDmtC6xkPlpNOdLWQV1NTBJvikA162HAqHmB@w2vHSstGG7nJtAVbWI8lUA3JQs0oLssvl7yxG@LRb64sQ2TboKZtuiVj7dpLgedaRJls1zYZDoS7StCGQApFILRuOYrfRSSp66gRGoLixvMdhxpfcTVYW8ydanbKBV7/uZ16@IRWvNFGU69Gpg/XZeqI6zBKwj1LVXdZmzewPlli@CmsrmsCOHzYuNGOweLUtpqJfhdZWs1Yw@tG6v6tuMcHyJLeuDF/n9GhsTBq4rFMvkjULMuA7h1GGXCFaSN1y9Mb44CXfoapiih5crgDON4VBlMQ8w34tIXhYVQ2z/WyQMOoHkZEO9ZJX@PdB@g7a911hmEgrszoYOVCIb0Xvt9LjF6BXL2su@50gE3Bl34oExuoLFqn3ByYLYdUc/nBn0eKwEnvcIo4eP2XLW1B7VCfrVYAikxW5IVfCh5omTiiFzXqgcjIuAdq@UiqlT5oF0bYCXrwttzZ0K3qOxPvGP7s@diiflhCfsm8fNcLWyxMfL6782x/e@9ob/u723svtqkkKfIbg@LpuEGSsvAMnXuPBG8pTDjEKXw@8eEcxxOH4izhDfxFL4gi9Riuux5cx990oGRn6hVy39xXnuTnvQy9yTqX32dmnozvSdM49NFEaIqqStC/M76A8/OwE5aZ@OEMJIdUqPU6RE8GHBeqgHsmbOacg/snrqRuQMGjCUIsG/BICQbRGXKAcptIvjHDSTPsw2r26qJjq6FR5BD7SzAOEZABgHzUup3XKYS5vVZh4D3gOZGNxLZyCGK4ez9qqudc7RZVq7a4X8hDdobB6Lgg3hOsFhDnBodWFQOkr@shJqMgqAL1FtBTII4094g71MD7QaNVbza@PpcG8SP2r8lbwQeY5H@gnfeinX5m/KQss30dA8DicS5SNnSJsEmZFnTZ0ZqSBnWpilakog8zJ8@3Jhf0t3/NFuQ5BuTSutVvxmj867XnvraZ9S/tY@GbN8PJJOCEVY4m30wV04uvz2Dnn4rVyPuZi1xlRfGt6US26YQEVHsf44nScom0j5Hz2NllgT2Kmoz4J9Ta3RLOKMWT6V0roWhrItgklebjeDSiiXw9JfqEBn1CrfxXpg6f39cMW4C4u9lqx@/Ra8s4ItHR5ntpwptAPVeouNva@heJ9ut6bbV9VGmfzJH3jAVpuOakuUkVadpt3r1TCTVwtnRhHV8if9EwN@Yt2qm8JYzTyuhydmiZGZdMqb@zUDCjtAnyFkmMLA6vlQwxJ9Rq2yQKXLOdUIiXe1RZ47pYHL@U2no8grGwlJyI2UJ8aauzjGODgajobEDbg3J6jhIoY2FsHsrk1Oi5yKtMFtqCTYh5gf/nYm1lSJANPL41svo1Gll9azXyrdXIt1Yjl1mNLN1sTMNJo@uPGsCaDVXtDLj/whIsqK1d9flnD/bV/mfb6vHLR/9SfX/3pfr8wTNI2VXPXz58svNIwf@3n73YVlTA/PuuN0GVewVTv@X1PJLOrzSbq4owLwQoX1UvOqfqs6DnvQXiuR92TjdP@KM@8qINLrX91pvMA34OGqMySyRWEyQr4rcmLXFCi@suUPIpviNqX57YRvLmGbJkiWwvKBy6MeDmtz3iQUiPi56VjNEGwAeQCmg6/CRLutP4tE5MS7@uZODMv/ceQWAKn75QD55tYaTPrZ39nd1nL9Tj3T34fP59dLOjtnbQbczDl5hFgE93t3Ye7zx6QAncgGZdoWyNDNYva0IdwWlUem8GUwwPNsRboXwlvHovFQqjQFtFhKo0HcXue/pAUvjuzs5O2@Si3bn1YO8730WuxvuhKhYxyKXlUF0sEG410WgEapMo2m12po6sZa3FG9LpXN3C7HaBZED0u6o08jK9E/ueKj5CMSI@SFPcbGbYNGqo6CbgRlTaEayrKAJDqVS9Tyg3oDaSHujaULA60B9YdFMcs@I9ckl7aQ0JKQZn3Bn1OIyuTgC6Z61uqjaaMAAKhCSBAVAGgwlR5423g0ISdUcgphFe/CHhLie8Ph0/PkOuEQ1cJeEhBwJZkzbxvNGUYoCjjj/ieUyYNfHuQDFSqEhI8OgkZzjUIldSiQP@X97Y8FUWIIuwCw5gZetLRfzsBtQAe/tJZxCFynHLKA2GK4g38llT63jYgeseyYUnaLD0FtUIqNo1F/9taEf1muGkQJz6CtOdq2Q7TLktOfi965aDkg8XakS9Peo0KkxJ/KcrG/BwoQEfggYQ1ez9At0KjSNibAlNMBBSdsIAKBKufOpHyahGQX/a8xIF5K7jvPa//LIsg1yNi1gqPtQ6o2GHoR7wIeQMfVCRmwu4xJCm5Am@RvEcOskexG/Dp6gMMcEG/kAPrtRmXx50jaKJI5UiP59Ta7dDxnBX1koUz7rBZvsaG59R9PwdslkePZN08ZpsbnMh@nNGJQb07DRBNy8DhYpF84hawsEdCvHe8SMVNg6@WHM3th6@qv3oB9XDRuOYt4VOnx8vWCmRn1noSg7Lw@hOkjagXmmCtBBOu1ha6zPybomrXCMDxuXEB@Z786ht8lisupg@onhZyXRKfPfO5VI1sjchEsJIMvHuVlUHusoqlTlUZUEQ753QWPSsq1OqhNPs15sY1x5noQ0jMsJ9hNRr7LBqpF9jebvGBz3YWQrCp/F0G/xlHYtcKIr@OfZ8NL5wHrqVjXJDQ9FiMsPp6C26qjG3ytKrC5xeOq8W0G1djg727@ujW7u0dXw8vBe2rUuxvVfbapV8XHwsWbiuj/ZHl6Dlw@2D0ELfq/mI@ZBcxGYo3RBn9daSpvkravzBwtzR2gM0ePZiRFWD1KptOhqihziHheLQNCpQttHEDNGL/a3tvT1V3EYp2zqUhX2vM@qRfSlug4j7pvZ0xHbItNnVDdNkwgQZ5kmnXLB5abLayxZz5uDlbBXCg1RlPMxmYaL2ws1kJtYRfLIQC4GG17wh6pFLtu5c70HhgSC@OEBNKBVPmtXBQmY3l/jwYSf7tMnE41Zl3jh8448NM@PNxFkXiaoncxuRZoTxOOgc48t39vx9zvzxuq6HGSzvh1PqMCrh99BfvnoBFY/xpbienMFLpkVPKemsEJUu6bEjs7wkh/3LE5SJxX4hvLC1rQtzLE1j/viWFcmO@NNNfOefS2bvVOSdeounlPv2hJbjQ89JHkHAZMI1WG3aVAHFDy/kCKPRMOekaxhye63dotYc6FZSNDPB3c4H@gg4@Dt309tDuirYbS@tqvb1VMWnRKImK@7WYg06EzDfvXPn9lW4073QxWu/LG4@Q9L7Z3Q6ftuxUIbzkFSFgHJ3nlV1fkwAlwydC7fAvqMXTKogsDoZZ0qi73QY2e2DtpxN0BYPGrP7cr@K8qJ0rWU1S7UtGzufSDZ2Alnog7WETUd51SyM/sXl1T2koG5X1Hfz/evjxYZAKA@/@AWHydwLxrhVAiM@OWKvqHAlXw9RKy7CEhx80Hj6tWJgbuo4lgccb26TX7jRRppr3IyCN6jXryNnSmyzIj5D1U874/N3KOB6RyJTzkObACnrV9Xma9ZR4ciam/2AlAgGJpTlJrcymQbb/NsjO/jmOqoPUh4DWA@YrhnA0sclBfeedZQq6FCTpQqnAX9ikmqcBLQa4d3DpC9zOtol@OPh3KQ3OL3vYeA5k3pfsJx1TMTL0oZApiNklooCTLJafzA/omE32Z9yNrAxJukjaQzcLYeBSb3JqahTpZMOpOw0TjrkJLhJmaQlgcKDyY9sWgo9780RTbJEmwOEpaoa@cPDuuhPferI3bEsJhwRTySU90b9Ak0KxTw1qPSRsImuZYWEDjb9wzopUMoGhHeyeGJ5IW36cQEbGNKt0JdMVFyMGoD/lUZIU23ixZoPNl8jhU@8sDf11PYM7/g6NqKmSnIMsqS2n22p3cdqb/f5dhI1tvgIeRQqpRX2KBSzNIy6o5dsFSY8mEYnR5yoP9O5Zx7nahT8bYBGwcQC4s90rq6AUBzislTn7/rv1AEc3mMzKU6/fCiTrnts@lDvBdNRdP5u9o6mdwacXh1I4FN1UUchwacLwyIrUThsTQ70FodhIZGvPNJuFeJaKIVqmYlvjkAsrlNrvnwh2Apm/4Spg5VJm3QckBO2SdwJAmR51iW@JQxH7yQOuElv2a5ynHTD8FCq1xeSK@oTE7jRsyPuJiu7ZiWVvEruxZUwhRk89RDjiMa1lVU/UO/8d7qy@FDBo38tfdsxo42@m2UarSOGll0CpnloZfOrhNXnfiH5a2HByQyqZLxRed3gBYFB3uPd3GUaT4ARfS@Amc1Bg/ECWoCjVZAA5GWyAEjlFzEeZbcyXnoZRbJbHK/Hxebk1BKjyyiSXUvc6ORUxGs9NRu9ALgzDkiCP47gImidr5kzB2SzUHHeYlXpgkKKdJ054jod/lPOqENv0wwB9Hiof7YO2fRGlexil8InR8RugXTeGhDcg8idCh5rdnornW4fSWrDKp6GsBqVAgacqZPq6rlgTyKJpDO01OJlRUZbEg0ceS05GmHLObRAiYRyQGtJUF41MSyAIghxcXiyWKC8EpOglWxQi/gJ3saaaqu1Gg1oJRvUWh8LWGtZWJOglTTowr5GG2Vy7A1Du@xcPnnlHD7WRmdV5c283jTik0Y7rYA1FMHysBktge77x370qYoZLfpVh/Yg0a6uiUdsnQYX/DufGNaHCmhW226CVBsjxN3C4qX8jIpZHGWzbzFjbpjHBDyHuMb3cQv0gCDsaVDsgUkaopkMudDoU0yzYvbQcKlZpNpkjKSKaukcPi@Q@z1YOufrDkd@L1aL5YsiN6ud2EWhTzpZ7kf37@uxqEfBka8y/7Wl8YQjGKskjnqcdMm/BI5pZFJRxFEdBj0WdlYRV1tf1g4gHS/g9LCTwoGvKYt90QUBzeHV7cAHlUUc2ISKuqxTNg59qVrEsXxtHPrCtoijdv120H0qqy8fXRsHXwSzcDSujQMpcHFMi0vngOCC/1vMIrXEeKBZlKR2qt0kaRicncRXN90XfVVVaC9IGBLws9RXVjuEMbdpfWhdg641HnjpWBwPx@eVtAFHMe3cTRYwt7BkeWG98OWWUlkCa628troVRn04COqDoVnfGYs/dUVPCUkEIck98BJT751M4IqEs1mX24dmQAgntP/oCFWzjo5IMvR8b/c7ew@eHj178BQvUUu8R6H4BrVlSF2nWV/BePYsbTkinSJXoaoFdqNA@7CVR@0TNNt0ilDkWCy1dG7BXRSZgcKaXJIX1UfemXoMWRS0fgEnQtaNbAamx6E2mE29WHtbLMeQ9gmmeyX3tQ1oCcEwnUhLCMZKLliXLS7/asQaKq9GryIG7KoDtskMD@32vkLDJaugUrW3r6LvepMu6pLUjNNSnkVUwce7GzmnQpULkaDHGKwJ/EWjoR5qp7hiv9YZ9tDl7XRAjm9P/WHntNvv1Mcn48IgdMU9jVMahOjksoDKVDv723svjp5jnK7tR2Q5gf/alLe/83R79@U@5ryArNuSvL23t7t3RArqey@f76PH0FRS0QYULDGYJCSAnu1@9uCJBcPfRWkkG4SEcN@EP@LKp6r88dGM/jsnM48qq0IcURAeMlPBopRWVZF/6gVTHbwN/U/oA76Klif4KAN16ajG5JDGQfGn5MW@Ti8sKGrHZDqOCJQ04J3USJSTJRjmNDzGAuSLKAS@nbTp6yxRxjw05AvGTqosGshgsYLYdw1CWh24TF7MRz1HoxNHntVzbwSQ@NpUmkaD2lrpooxeJcekNJQuXGrAydEg56il7JIygqKVXrCCGNli13ZBG7wDFFmU0CTElilUgF8Q26pS8cvnBTtAlGTBrsrxo86VZUOfhJH4NTesOWK3pqznC/UjgZhfYoFjaIQ/n9uPUkRg8j5FxhwHaHluxoz@6s6yhNkxs@PQ@1Rs111H7ZFH0OAHkcOOXshnX0x38twlDTjCjPSMJ/MAvbyNSYepQqbxMGrDQEWTuWILwjAywwU9P8T/zsS1aw8VaBwguLINWyxyLrujRCOhMGIAuuYVN4rrsRsbNkswisMMcd@GaGVBfGFDrGRBvLUhbmdBfPVjBvEHTqWiJ29Drdy5w9rMifnMKP5/TPFaTcPe16rQcWHAZxfXpzEj2WYcAl1x0RzUPrMBud2yu5e2LIn6q/8LuG1cUqpGlXDDL2n2JZh//m@K6yyhu8Yo/T730NqgkDmRJy82YUZ54SMhcd0ksSVNY/urS7AVi3oWs8v@QUwRX@QQzVd/nYDJJpuf6HlXZvz0C9eNuGwrtmpII/jLRQTu@yA44vJ6fZG3UTbgxeyVdYNF9yBGwCC3bZCVNEhWle8urbJp42tlVtmyQZrXqfKrv5U65fzKgPhjA0F7rQxmJuj/Syw0Us2HQlmgIUOiTc3z@NU3F/w42Qa7WBb48xg7FTm8vN0//410u@OSmfD/NpM4qYBNX3raMwf@f14Xx@1cHD9gFLVa7riVGKJSyYX46mdxO3h408vsskXy839/delmful/HZeOj/kNfXAz16CRpbdAox6UzKSiBwYbzx8MgEnJaI11jJo1Zy05PIvFYCzZgZbJFouzZPaKzp5nZt822SnkF8xgaS4J/esRY3SfIwwSaxT/JitfZrh05oZrc21l7pDN7TKzLgbmMDaGxxFTHIvp2UhdOJYTl4xF1JJbFmbvokBccDvz8hN2Jp2TUQcDtIbBqC4RQPygsX0avPbxoJo00M1F/XWYdxv6ZVhrQkD3OBevrw9QoQKaKk5FWPeb7@0I2On1pqfTIb6huXKvQsdIjQa6jKOL4Gh6GgpOPHEfTv0h9MBFTi1mEeGaN4ZW0ikMrPS1qk9VnVXtYpWNBuuN18kNHSVR23oTfxxRZe7iXQBdPhGDClX49y1YzcKjgfo5IWJXtK7054k/8hwLHqO4@lUrgfwiVFwu1SbKSI@JhaOKGiDPpqcJDOcy46Qb43JOPUSLH6dZXcGR85Bu1MTDCCHGOsIP1Yr4oCPXMohELIgmSSwr1dUyjxIheg7keZqEWK2uNLGiMWaRiyLyDG00yzsDcltERq2Eg7AZaJoF4Ahj9DKuG03oHWSYdrnFf/iTH//3Yvm80dBpFFPHH3XgzkARSWKs@LkfPNffFnq8n4itYgr3/4hxM@q@1/NPOxihJrJQA3HlYIYJRMznQGjotCoYwn4THDuWLxhdIRJWo/Fga0vtf7a3@zlaQ7EQgaggVRyJYF0VKzzsVDKRL4rBCCKUsAjzVCpGIN2IRSjTKwQzPSb3OgPH0sCC0fqt/0ijRbL8ADXdeV2mEGJ2kZ36oJwQdWtttGYiNAXjPPzWf2DMwZi1Z7MRB@OiECb8HHtA/FoU6Sz0iyGy6/v7P/wvVJ1YlADPh3KVU7vqPKafcg9EIEs0W2sd5vYqUQ0NQi7iK4fod/6MkIUcpFtvhIUb9q5okGR3@49/VxEOfHyA2bNKqgSeypWIfsKIzOsBjVwuvtqV@H6P8fV9egWwEXXnyS4@hXOyPkGjIcdKblwxfH//h9JigPcjfDO5pI7lRHMLmZPxF/bMUlmZjrz5tfDnzvAf2UjFzDUPIx9UmXh@/LfxMrW7ya6Tmb5vWKsz1bTMDv/4b7Koj3TMYfWgB3BGa09V5lrJafNv/rbBPyvcmF1BMP/wJz/9WdzHWW7PZrn9@Wm8mmaLvZjltf1Gakv6Hh4Zxcosdyr@OllNYuXOXOszD8Ff5Y37LDnYs7wlD6RvFv3simWfh@QnGolZ8LMrl3wert/TuDIXe7pbOct9lrvMNfachZ7Cv5zTTFiMf24vxtllM5@75vPJ4r8RcmT40Hh0YVoaDeFwmsTa3lct@oueefHvRro19u6HoraYcXGBowJ0eGtK0B5Cze7bK/88HVP@gvmaOLUlzhZ0j6xaWlILXE06wzCjKtf92upawaGD615GLRsfVknhotEYeWx0Px338dZB73endPOY0PMfBg/I3hl/g@YSuG24rrC1DbknOKAmH9ILTrhAPoiOfA7pqwZ6gO7DdYP@3jfdrbU4he4bN9JYhgGzRDdInI5XodyLiNwkKq3DzEsF31MzF8L/MjsQ3666fLvCwZI@kh/ZOOfKzft3fmZ2JDNKQRJ7CmXlapx/KtNAKkb0Vk4eO4Sny0ftJr7MRSqZqo@A3KP7f9u7Raq6fF7SAsvD/Af/yRx0Xoi6rH3oD5q8ksd/DI6JA5N7Alr7J/8kBE55Od4ycmv@z3riQ96h8irHk@wa9eRU82f/roiknT1InN2@@pIlGHPvWGrnmXr5YntP7b7cf/5yHwUytmNEcwfPv@jxtZv3ZbrAJoUEC3fZNlzzV/g6a@UxeflVv7JSpu7/159i9xltxS02i9YwXVrujxLlWrrcJWNEU3HtEZLxWSjPQgtoHdctvXXdNRkhuEDvjCJcr6EHPwSMBRPs8FnONiZ/Npm2b91SMeO5xtR/nd2yhDH5wgQ86nAC3JbC@XOb31LGN0MZJLKa4@udm/Wax/ihF9rlJ4F@0xSUkGxmC3zPzs7qAwxPNZ34dS9E90QhOoZrjI@BWRgFJNREt9lAeH4P7rbovHDaexP/qvU6o7edEBVkPp2hSrR77@M5/y3kyYjHx6cciuND5cRKkbS3Oq/2qoCs2u29qQ7O@m3JYMNgo3DCicj9TPTHaah/@eOBgQgilLObrO7wTS8YErdb7A7hICvGVXMPNeRcf8r32GfDGC1Enov3U0VMs8OKFAofDSgHfgJXpa2L/dnB/DBRfGaKJ7RZQo6IeSlSVgjGfNbjoLABM86fxZXqag9m4izemJDh6wMqhWhIRDPXMAmLcMyZsVL8Br5QYRpCzhNpaPnTc6m0Hm/@gnl0NWEATYxhwD2ncfDFq4NXh6PQO1s@rDSOq@joCKG7YtZIY0o@e/g3jv7w7XAchImkkRdGrODS1Em9E6EGphVWfJGxSmncQLOMwo0fDxpqB7qUiVv0g8jxxUyVtHFO6Hm7eFCMx5gbdiCNwZH2tZKBpOHDk2VqbyM6tBBhuumSjsSXpQtV/HyC/rQ0bA3GHB3AjOZoRoiBGpJLRWKYqotkq/C1jBNg2NkHbqorOh@m4iCVZXXzQubfbv7N927@ANZFduuJYHlTTCmNzTzYcD1ZLuwRc8O15hVa0FjuDNHlX3F7RO5ptOJgub3c0KYpXA92QYLOWpPfE8cT/JI6Ei0UrGuOd181d3lZ8rrQQ2o0TeJXeMrXhCDleQPhCCIZxTwpNrOLwU2XNw56FssqdmY1ckaNnHERhp7lNPJQimEgT9ttwyE6bevAeQT4WqzRS9dCFXbeYnwqdkW03DB1xnsOUYG2MIQJRTrrHWbWfmA12tq0UgiQEBcQ9L1BZzqM1gvpDa9VM19mj@Kh1HsUfwkZ8F4BBEZbcJuVyhxDZPJigaJ0n9xewq@DQrFVbVZb9L8m/79Y1Yn6/63FxGYSspVMbFZT//uVJB7iyGZfi1rNVdyQC79YUuN5dBKMVgpLypzZis5s9EfIL6ivQ34fDkf@eOxFFOZIHXsjfNzGwK9@gBILdP6FcXXg9xuP/Iusa@SKn2KPXodHiOhIENXHc1W8tVmEcT8dB5NIfTn0u/o3xii/u6q/wnmIbqRCzyMeKAQmSJ65Ud93fzLfiXZHKJdooMfkKODf3WHQbZzCVd6bkCvHENY8QPhBfTIdNcjdlDfq47M4mSF03kDTTqA66Fr/CMCOsFtOGSkv9NA9ZfHVbDAokvMWb9h/4SHjhtIjZSKp7PSJ7@iEJ0Xc1pbUM2DC1tndivZhYrx00Yh7qiSPcbUhx3MmjYGSFekLNd4xliVpZhRRKVre68n1X7FOD9BQqlgmtswp04kYRDG8VuWUAqwYkiiBfcQgfcwY41kR9whDhHpoWSKNqCglCdSO@FMqjROoIjmf/Sqwh9grbUXrOTCtzDO21tG9J8rK3FbZ7BQ@2km11tYxNgf1BAcUp0mehltrmEMOKkOFEefYN43dj4orLQFAnhAKhAg89gQ9MnRfkxIpCuvg8ED6q@s8FE900SXakGK8oPxq5B1TlBR11vU5FEzfDwkASzaOv/THMkTVBKl2p8fAatNaoMgqfhhOvTufrK1SgyiukQbtB70E6EoDMKNr2QY17iQ6HZpe3ItO1NB76w3Z/xs3m2K/8KIkOnNk@0Rx890ykQ4MZaKnMArOvSqnbW0/fvJgf3urqmqtOwjOBqoG1rEGl7MrlE8GHEJGWISXb717d5WJ3Amrpc1GqSxN37SHvWI3WCOAPWuC97ixU3KpmEjmGDFcmfq4V1VNvEUT2w11tXG5YVOmE4xaUNSDq1f@0lIRSRrrWkISTGyOUKYcHxrwBRvPAlDuXgEjILvbEV7CMJQQUW7x/s1azaypdfpVg421VttgO/PiI7iHv1GlvekosduWaO10VAk2OfSWx1vbzRLtC/ViW524pY/CUhu5c8M5vXWm5XMd4m80wFY4PHD7wcO5nj9nqrVWYEDKB63DclkSSn/3/@HadxGbBQydqHyO/PWXrnYJW@dNfZs9aDollgZDsS/rkTeLHtHmGrlR2xToBv15nUKS9h/B2dt3vrTrGDvlc9Ju7rnu7fI5VDkZox3KGDZDbx8wltuYNkikxVeOV69G6BZ3Ge9f33v65DOY8j30LxVGB18cLt9qVEslOOJJA8nFSB9qa/fpc5QkTMp1kig8ngSnMi6Tjqmkjg/7aDlMra8WsWsNXIWwcx57kfQ@fDjf7xw/65zCjbkDQ5AU4HRsrR8Mc4@6/PYYucXk5BbL58cuQZ1MvEGbOaGL0H3rHJfbEfw5sau4A1W4KyuEPYJCLjoQSI26P4LT@rP9p0/c0v2OQqxuxqooVbqGOIBQiGAcTKILbYJ0MJwuUlXEdptEMPCvUipuJPtyv9HZKLUvLnLb8yTo9NnjVykm4L4zrQrFTdzFKW1PYiqYjz0XE/ho@872frEKZfHui4kU42hOmxY7I3Z1HUxuuFPQETh/gTCuu/rxx5SGRaah6640m2VUD7kAbOQDAtDywpq0LyYdt@@YgeyM/TqJzr0Z10XMyUp9pdEZhWfAjjZad5v3bjc/DSb4btD3wt7HIWwhbgdDyvrR/GM05Cd1suNgOPh44A/xwerm6vLarv/wX33v3ou7W06v@y@Ahyy@DgN8wJ@M7QZMOmei/Qd77KTH1EWNGAHOXqcx7rwJGqv9Zm@tudb6pO99csdba95e693xbt/r3rt3rzdYXev2733S@eROr9tAt9FUpH5KyoNFJn@sdnC9avMYs7WV5r3BoNW6@0n/zr3BvZXm7dur3bU7/ebq6mCt1bl9@25/Za17r3s51xa3pwAbrN538exI78Af5TN3hYW9XUqX/xE';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxx                              # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU  ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $f &&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le./_e _=B[1;#]>847576097 @Numun Cr gu8IO nd eX"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t}a,
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);(!)=seq;instance Num();f=(^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/michaeldv/ante/blob/master/ante.rb).

The code is on line 39: `2♦10♦10♦10♥`.

Explanation:

```
2♦    ♦ = 2
10♦   print ♦ (2)
10♦   print ♦ (2)
10♥   print ♥ (0)
```

Comment: You seem to have run out of Haskell extensions, so I took a look at the [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153744/) and managed to get `OverloadedStrings` without any others. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoMwDEDRnVNY7K24ABsLE0OXbpUBAxFOgmzT3h6DRMf/9BfUlZjdQ9yyGDRo@HyZhDQXIalhGghavQWavPdM8FtICCbJ8e@fuioihlRvV1pZuh/DxDirP97dl4QzjjTes54 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Small note: If `Double` gives trouble for some reason, `Integer` can be used.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen `Double` is ok, but `Integer` gives one byte shorter code in the polyglot.

Answer (score 7):

## 221. [Red](https://www.red-lang.org/), 10420 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM3@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WHLKtpx2pm/pSzozbX1KSqIk2hTJJClbSqc/VNcsaqem@6GnprbRl52uqt7t3V5ggGks9qEH04sFpl8HjfkNXz8tGgvUP6g95wRJURc7nV9VY2eBoS0yGHHiRMSJEydO3A6bktX7zW@CeLEjXR11Vd1mtmzZrG0qN7KZYBsj9lxSrGw6EwggVNXsDvqyZlvFQJCJjClaS2nDO7P1a1lTPskm@KcZM0y9a0p9Zvckm8lWSzJki@kD2xjYTO/Mj5ZhrNbXr5Q4xuwrWhfAbNk0TNmm8BXGzjRV6jfb0lRIdipBw4Rwi23J6uf@Z5u19H5f0toWQOYY29dNS0b4lmxZOkZfZWxYk1tTSPMAKpmKvlc9eDEVVGDsBWRRMlR5yKSmZZtSy1Z0DWmSYicHZydHUzFEkb053d6e9k2zV3FdY9uD1vV0UIadmZakStP4V1h1YOu79rR/llW7siaxdKKQSE8H5tiGKc1EWWWmLLU7iionoEJYnPVk1ZBNhj6so5tsF7Kk5lP5VKM6jploYdz8OHAabYGpmYw9VZ50Cgivmz1ZgxympgNFL3AqIO0FtBVKQDJHLGz1dBP4yGQDS26zW91sA3Np6igSg/hs@Ik1JUvOrSCCjIfgWtNvNWAiW4eqbY5smWm6FqfICLjCxL3GNGOls@hbPdyd9s@x9N603yowWuu6M1uX6Tw71o3RtG@B7St789g5k@INYVNvQ21MhYnsSAIvSmaS8Jn0ZCtoQe1CY2ZXFmSsLTNLUwxDtnkg8IpsUjDEZqqiXfMGfmTq7UELG5/dkyFtbLDID1agBbEqzHDERAIdLEgcxMEgByd6X/bn12KaDBVkGXJL6Sgtzljy0JY1C7JsJZgChbhVVJW1ZRUijLG3YszSsXrHXk1V6iVaiQAyJqbC@tcqU1jLMBgPglJAlrZTeSYj9dgnCFd7FhsafWYpfQi2W3qnI8vsk2z0IHqgrQcYXC1jqlje25IMMJrskkY2QCAgaXSkNNDJpdCtKQFpTcuhga30gbCKHbKYLFkKClSIYslam6hqeKJWZ9IEy7MbBRo8FH1gEm5LNqnJEV5onqYMKCWvmsO3pmLb1GpYlR3JkslOTVmOTIrdiSQhMR1TsLEgCarUtbVQ7XA7BJXLYyQkAyrTzJy@fhmQWKLMlhol@JUFoRSoHWyxu6VLdHMpCwxgmGEpwsrfMSt5eSnDbyg2k13zPgBYA0AVlSV1w05KcQMyGLchg0kJneiK36QThupLmK1N1YWP5ThUG2oDhA97E6OStQamiT3JmKjSNRRa1bUu0BMKaw40pIfGcimogpYOHUGMyTdANZC8VEcgF5DCpz0FKs3CKvE1LN4fEkGhRwQ2dijqpmvp6oDgIKZlIy8DVSAqYtztsDesIykqRoFwRMVzbcrWQLUxzkBrY81Dfye3E8zNBjVYE/j4BpKTACl5AOv3fe2SMgXAUBE6FRWDvv/DP2t3u4Cn2mqBbHPY9Q1r6y3quSXKLHSHDBkWBKpK2QK4GKbOo0MCN5KqtElASNrISYIyQane6gO1zXRI0LxVoJX2pBto2dC4WrbMmZx39jHWl665NFE450LB@1ITKpYSoLSp2HH2fBNqqSUHgsQz8f7A7uRZ3KixkJX8NrxeDK8vXsqQuUgisryUTHZLwHCJZfKCt9BjnPOmOiEpLVuydKUdMEZ2T9fSLN5iQqusG7IWDk3gCMVCZjMUSaCUC0dKSrmV6ChaOxxaA16sQMKhSKlVbl0oxXppKro/SUBzi2iwucrhVkQIgMihRnGT7IM0T0Dn8CbuuHxhutVAkmNwwueNhJn2u@EeQVJ2kC91ZBCQQwlLlWUjnEqIERQTCDe33Bgwr6RTOJwCF5V6NBQMRf1FJwxQ0omCYmM9VXQUW6rRw04LiKJZBvQEJvJuC3pqlIyWYoPGGWNN4mvqRUCykEy8lUOmjF26x0fUJHmTw/hxFJQOhnETmmzJctvXkEEIQFu2rRlprOq3kCDlCbsZEB0aJip1oWogMi9IlReEp0Q@k0XiigZga8osH28q0AiwuYFMd3jeVzYAz6Q5DGDjjcQne/rSCLC0eLc6bjBM6UBb6oN4AG2oJaPMAeEj8w4FExlQ@7NAx0ZtOxVPZ7OTbWymidlmshp/D0L6U/LRloSF9zcmFDSsI98yVdK6A6krc02MSa2WbNiOoIKSWDaIoun@hjzjTueZsHqBpefTaVMn4qoW4zRQyPPac7pCCaWLo@jHQZ2RmeQMVUBzNEEsqaPp1AHgZipx4QOCTGTgg/BAFlwNAJhMHsqtgQ1SDRj4tqe0esCzmDuNy0XeCU0nD17@1EGyxzte0pgZsfIsHUgkPS/MxoMo4lijs3igc0VUlQkPqny/x@OYJas/B7HuZRE6Ap9vIiklgPe@gLOva/ocpEBIDy2CTIbwegBN7AQVSui4XLWLGqunZXpVBHWGA4E28l/Ptg2rCP2EYvcGzQRwSvLUHO3ahxoyS9I2R4qtc3dT1Zsgli1on0k3hWRr0FSGUwUiP68Or6zADShgHYuVoef@OACuC4c6FghM8t9EYF@QQIKbUPC7AIAElABChTsWieJtEConI60VFhLUlBLQ6IQYE7DhCjDcETCWR5dNvY9SiJ2TYoCaHgz7FA3HCo7MJ5Evze3qPNlPel0olLjSFS18F1pcXAwVQxWQ7IuL6@BaQ9c6uqLgWidXnFwIl0AXxYiRC0MvKAb61UP3Fy7mYaSO1TbEXumTYoSli2IxU49JF6LzTOMzAqIOJBtAx/EBeEKRchmdkYhQuYWCJpqdydJvonQ@aZmK4RDhpXQj8XeHChkig9I3cBhpyiXsZB@nSb9sQi8ISmurFzZDlxepy/rl3WU7enkfimHsSEkqN6FQkF64n@ia@gC6y8jFSjEu1iORiwx0ks1yKBVaDofzcRUSkiKRb/KRqMSpHQ7JILXDl5chIKpDn4tWzyR8w1g6EvFIBfnAjhl0wnAocZeH9JuReiQagriRUAyGGOVQCCjTQiJYVGjkzAkCHR6/4oTZjEYDxIa6eY2/GbEPfgkYYPHo28C/myeTw97@NUhX1rJUVEXiJtdG4DW5zD3b9PA0riLbJY1Vg@4WSgC9bdsbGeFoXBuQ/kzKre5PiIaDCEF@2PegXFUmYBBxRxnCAAHa/chVhLD/Rl1oEwacuionzkk1ERg0HBz2yom52tAR71YSLWvMA6D3gNNQpRY07El0lwK7BITA58nk/JBIaQbxtKpEo5ovlRE6lpakIf3aCmntA8XqIXlBs8KhhNkBqqLKDrqBTFTbZS3o87tAaXmo2FyHBz46wSg7khWOoNZY5VoXKnuoMWCm3DkA6s71Fox3ZNAcMJQPHllNu1FMXUMiJ2qAGhi@hHUwhXweeYGNqtXd9NbD9J2HHCg24y36aOvHOk3cltViSU1X9a7OlgEAWTOR4Iy9q@FUCeh8NgwvmaV8IgJVu7o2muJBGbt7C3VEMZfxtG8JIZMEn7gCWcPmF3oM8ECZT3bf16CHELOpFOTffUvR5RXSh2W6jOjZYmMAZ8pWRb7BmnwvG73RxIQS8gcfRQI/6TJvmHxcL0GHCrlyWvgniupv5NwH2rkb1HZd88peIw0JpzL8o4yJ0oMyCO3UKQ5vNlDC4JQ3@rqkmEA6U@Hj@kXBdZmckFvewCne6eu2lHyT6FkMbwHUF@IKE6xkaDGUjMfxLlAQS1dYsi3fJFFKOZhBKp/2BnJAbvV0JlyC7uIHEkCE9kAJj0MhZJPUPC@aMzkdsPUB6IttWVX6ir1LE2mqhkrRuMN3Q3E@cIzgSJHtgDOSGQtunOwaS3Gty@GPQSgSVhg7JHjJTbmdXOahtSF2hFZApic7ONyqNY6qpztlITmwzKSqNKHltOVGHxReVbYENn1hApCUE//TtXqs63aZs8m1yr54BTGOG31vq7G3u3FcPX7HM0FoLKU/UCXMSnFpCgCjn1Cw25p9848dU@97IwHLqaalDFaMPLHWgMNiJ3QFQwfOSoPPP4f@fVw9SLQC3VaLxXX@6nk6gKsIiCsK1Hd2o1GEpBUGz9OBzBNKXGVImE3Xs4Ce3vrCxMz7GN288IcjOZjvxNQ9Ire0gWX4SnYniuR/Y3c6qC143mnyvo5jE1PH3hny5usTkysDDllmguYCe/hWCB9f15iLbyZoLrCHL8vx4XrIfHRTIfNAPWQ5QobrJ3NxTQXMAfQwrRIm/5rLOCxPYQ8tuDhpzQ1@MJKHu0C4cVFmjIqWaBwvFzDNuaPPF0ysBs7NjnkkLU6EYhBfZmHxNgyK1hAE@eUzLsCAF2iPltFO2EN7jCLjRxEHXYcvv3jhnBFEtSE1oFWOc@v6@IJYXAXxJubGkbNeZH0qqq6MvT1wXq9ptQEiYOBr0q6PP8iLxKvQXefxN4o0r0FTN0a@tnyX5sTvK4448bWuDCc3ySHUysyJQE5tw13rmQjjzZKv7zSu@CRhw1newXrhgvAUuvw9HRS1PcWiVVe/ZAx4A4rLgOCOiibUf2Eckh7PTrL4zfxpVcGPiGQ2iNVrHQfjY1cjlRCziMVD0b9WZ2N2QKel2wToTKZmQ3hf0W926DYHoOjM2EGniUtQSJWXuOqAk4o6jDDkWwKjuQenmwRFWEoe0wNnIeblZ3I@ZSIzTbkzAOU7CYNDdH8BLF7IE2Sn2VQeAgW6YNbd59xCHg9gAJROrCREd7SF85cw4uKTIae7hwQI7bc3MwnHJqrCHpg2xHKe/@lHbaiS2QrrSSMagniOBlCSuKXzYP05UfGFbvPrmmCuBqoiEWHI9SWULQnXPSTVc8xHjToNi8d7ktlHTd@pbmBXvEF7e4TzeM5NWR20Zfc5P5EiIyJPTvYxTemz1hxogp2al@SJ0dhO1aU2kYGPwBSZIplY2bwa5CEfi/hUXRBGDyU0Z/qQjdfr7N7AHvA7LtF9qRoVA38PEWECNpWVmqKc1C2pqciPVLspXQ/aety47lKhMWu5ObDj8jdxtiveUaVr7mygcz4BeBFNpduVTff5ENhtDwYVNBpK3tLjEc5wVStGyrL0GE5T5feHQNxNMp7jYTopKt2eUNEeQxGLtKCRIGlxHT7uI5MyRVhVao5wVNj7es7CBElnBTlTbkWjqQx2st6iy3jF3zAejo89M8UvFObH5jsAOEnmjVmSfOU/zmfEqMzOXoAvNHLoupS@pMbTbZ/zQSnuzraOXXNAaYog3lIlC5jJdqpDvoHqo9tjDI69UQvZaux6hL3H2XHX3h5axnFaqdOSW7qqWNic1Yek5vTM9zhN3INBt3FUfJslbJvUYKsX91zzJYHesnEN5QFGe4Jk48sXuEDk45yE/hDRWvot/h5ULnr6jczv8zu3T3Nz9QQZFVeJJZTWXAHabn2JU3Ednm7z6Xg9N192S53r76wWTA4FnsrLlqLqFozJ8f4YKUC7tix@n8/FfqopkhanSW2/e340J1MGSziTeA/UpaR2dTWX7yYluD1Y4QOzg5LfeT5V4nkSSxS/LLFcPUjXROf5oKi/TprXX@IEmvk2cYXM53ykn50ntpyVlYcLCOMHXPaeX7jtVJ5iJpJ8guShCjBbvVtp5D5/QG/yEHXd3sQYkV4Nah5GKOTBYZtc1/4hqa08nlr7aSJpBu3qlwrhq9xrVYbOi@4zVcrSKfErY4ip1NMFVEcdyAN5rnw6bF7JuPHxkdHG0zOVcoqx5EwlJoF4OJHoQX1yRo1PyjX22/j2qICRVAUa@Re1m7nyzgBd3MCB9hE4jtAxG7GrDYyJyp0YrWnHj1OuZ7gtW29PZBJDvlYi5b@sQ02o65ZMv4dU@1pfh7Gx3ge1QXtC/TtIadaD3ycQk89Y0ZiYHJmbvLeMDrosqB5Qo8q1FcdZ86cJnfRDA3oCLhSSmqLJ9gjvD1F6nhBt6rr6NTUDsrSt0AZnNY5bWr9UQzNqjrOjgo2nLiycBml2Hpq04P2MM7gE6uG42X5kpOyfinpkNDgzrf5Ib@WbZP/S@BJ6apoVssyW636IIWnyQ0zkE6uPsiPXQvWmrEr8McytPIavkMg8is/TOhz1lpZscJmHL@yM19yCU6LHGAGxlDaMTXpyX6bXR5R6qX01sNzHg0BDHX9zghNJWoh4IJ6hQFvX8D6xiOTThmxdg9GULZldGYcjKq6bOr4PyVd3fWMucXf7Ulfm5x8eEx3jWQncascHcWPn/PmJIt/90oJofHPA46wADedaHlnucy7C/VEL6nPQ//Ks2lQbb@Hs5xcbdSI5d1nnC@qe1tN7Wk/umdQ4vLeHmgdwpM1PrjxWCMh/T7KucW8hyaPxaK5n@amr6qr6FOqiPOTSUdfnT8zW8FxAG6J@Fd6R1IQA5/HFGTvosolI1Hc/1HZ68gB6Jku3dUOO09tDoCpO9vD7/Lnm3cOQxc4V2WzzjRGgjkPSSlOV2a0CWbiy/KvS8yeSmqou4fbVR5R3oIz7fMrUVEs3vzjv0ZV02zDo0TDUgUU3mtGN0ymOecXdppw@hRkUm@9J4Swrd/Vmq6d8KUtNWbI15TrpzuHw10fHpY4wppIrLL6F3glVAVqZowQyQdkffoKP3Yf6P98SztzSbw5Mc/RlwTC5H8CbauUrBOh4KH1ncXZOMHX5uOnK3Vz0yDKFs5b7IDeRAo3KclxOgVYiPjgDNLG/zJFetKj4gNIzVW7KjG8d7WumLp3NADSJp/i2O4D/vMmLhwThjiPfYFQY3hl0rciXGbfXBp0Kb3MRVrt4lIuvJFmqfuubaIamL2nOY26v7K06PrYEkn10DSSRdNY64/LgwdktVTEsfmfxTnoultnF@1mo0fyRrlM9bbnDlynQ9SXNrq@buMkeVIh4y5StFs54o/TlUpGLHE3vghSOq2wM7MLOLcLsfoF5uslkDxd/eyB3Jdx0t6fg/jvVmu30APP01oGnIH49kCzl9UC35bk4p7cQPAXlvtRVWjsTteAidKnr7NDij4lGgF6zFXHbUyza6@w65jcczma0Gj8bOD2p7p25e3wixKcXOVtOWXyXuVtTPQdO62O4NDetSa3TWYh/UNApNk2YOs@55Zy/3eKxWYTbQd8YWM5jfup9PLngnznuX5O/dauAFIx/BKHLepJqz59d9k2egj7l9IRj50Na9ntF1bvsfT7FQP0CAYdK9wOMtQH98pFkQwvQ5jArpf/EdUucm4hzpcb6CIwgZ1hc0RT78XkY25ZgHOQ@sUBc1cKTOck9vCeefy2G@Ol8quw9KvGhSx@1VBjZfAnq6N0XIOTNL3ctX1h2ga5S1wZ2HE8zPtZF5B7tIopsmM/5eICFX9f2zyIuK3R7Lb7T8QuamCXDiG5gqaOx68HF/jkcpuAp7oeF7GwMd2iwJXekgWof44reU@JVDUPFmQ2Q6Vv6vCHM0Qi6mK8aB0EvMehvyS1cCXxSHg70fVDPoN8yQKr2j2Vcup8SJA9Hxqh7ektSgWbtJyV3QujnlfVUMuQNqHP1K8vLMW5JtjQPq4yzf50vjd@LuBrUlM0rfqL9UcjZHOzIQxpaPMwyXLeJ260WV6NxRm2ipfgG2ZAXQ//CVCXociD7v3qUn8BdtRO9WXzOVIuzJZeOJXsH2KyYs@8a/BTTOT1rJdwj6kHao07H2dzjTSyIh@wGqArbuplgBBcOS9FoJBLgkXA5sasBmAtFh4TxACE/f2wxkDg2wSoddnHBlu6GxVRRvGdlJhQFVq9zrHjRcbba0KATvsc8@sWSVC8vheLx0FLoUiuyVMgDl1XoVOeCSxOwHYUePL9jEjBN4icR0O2WuMQPSFo9OnwMA8g2DETPNJofxkEtP@bHz5Ce4n6lv/urtnMmuytDYfsKKLZAEDRJoPflnn67ztN1UgdxIeGZbsQBOpDKTxjGN6sMOmcYsfKj2PotO9s@zTsHPB37B/ByxEc0Xi545eKcKR7PsHnl8dx4W@2dhL1YbqGgKxj0NXartO2elYDGQycvBuZ4KzO4EEyzTZwoacfYLmvLuE2EDtTQ3KCq69d0Mg5z8nd/xY@10rEa57iDmzwdZ/eliKdnRDpL2mrpA8i1i@STbOoOSBiJDBrRAGfdGXaS5B/BwyZ03hY4Mu6eNqVk@JHTzeoJi9dYCE074CG2ktIJL1WPX7y5SNXL37F@Uv5PP0pG7hzCCd/ECzlLiDEXpHSPjOUPzkLwODTEhKWhwBP0zhwpjoi/5fUBJJI4k@GxI5fHdN1wWg1ZDKAD8h43OpZrwuimenaPnfbJ2AAxrHxLx05pR76GAh5P8WsWNDB4jRBq3urKS@EBnxyOn9gsCwni0V0JXNw8AZ3CwSOUGGVpyD6zHjIZiBIxm4I3TkgVT@32yxvuxsGMf3tncktuDmhL0006kc6UqThLjfJahVwgpXQ8PX/x7eUwnYpfDldr9aTlEvXycvhNKv0WqK6bEOtZElte7WDrbilRSX3@bEkjJgj3oRLfjgpiYunuaPeodnJaPT07gVq4d8XPtm72pbGsQS6isx49XSW7BEAXU5Gtr5A/3huAh8NsSWJraHEnEgn4jxMQqENrIS4scadPNE3E/kL0efEt2Rc@C@DItI7CXI7ahR4E6xCYDamGhR8YaF2BOXGdE@LEZQrKeGxAHmFw0@8cWUqkElgZiBUHYj2RVOzhwq5zv6dQ7ItYHifb@lwQpJiX3oUXzos4lwT3v5NyG9BR/vbl5lgeLzfBPFJuAPV83Tjb1d29s@PaZDTgMXqS1C0Xss45Gi6csaXxeWX3SDwddXQi4sR6WWACReCvTmdG5pSasn0rQ7Ec4djq88jEoZR/ITBmTKBMGW1S1UucFuEw5QB1kBIWa@qYT0cZ@rLo9tE@dHe8iJ4Q2BY81G7GE4KDOUj2gRJ4ucVArA653KZ3RELckdchy6/@xNwWh0XDPhrG7BTrga7K63UsBv@@Xsl1petsyJzuTKyzOEvDT5W1LhTYhY2UeB/FljghhCWed8HLL9qmgTy1rySa36Idp85JJuilVclAQxgO9IFuy0X2caDTcU1XmHj6xS3OnkjcDBNVbUvC0tAxUM1GoxZuv0X4drdPyqidcdWM5Luf5wYadlQA5DOKBEMzE@1XdUjWc/MqnOS6Y8nD7SppwcNyTu57WoLFbhSLFkSwEjqo46ggKbE0TsHRIhkd1GVV1QKdpA3dN7ffRcpJgo5F8LMRcY0JQeDJhKcyxpgQQFirPGvZAbrSWxgntD7wyEsER5gtH87Q2mI8DpTrKpprQauI6zY0oV1ktjnA3UWV0EwUNwtFcsV7dl/1Ac6xcXMpJ7//wz/jdm0ubXD/1HEPUxvw9vvOWwfcf@CGiCK8/SvvLQ1vP@Nv3yaxymaNeTjJO8P5B8@QAF8@F2bKhDLBNSNGZfFqG2v6ze4Rs2hxCeuyLw191YQSBnlO0YBeSh@Y4obqGMF5CuMqHOMJX7wBFgG@Av5A9QY1GkpPNuthNOlQTCYx4zgDlqCDB/KQryyRhYePA7RsBEpYMpfNrYhJyGT8xkVIx6y7uPWdI4xEiiATAzeKUf7QbOGJJiZYMPSWy7kS543kkvRtRvjgZXQJYAN8oHDBIA4egvJiQFjFiRZekqJiBKNiRxYSQyjT2jpnNdAGw@QAkAh6a@5pUlA3dYdUwMeaPLRJYxq5A6AmWrDDGXGZ27dyEcUBEceN9nemm@N4Mzse/vE10IS/GoRzBDtBsKIwj1kvvmWX9qVWd@wwMWC8X85hXQ3c/3KOcSbOWXjwfNYqUHjapg@Whj0/0XQ89LANuWXhdDKdSYq5iI9DBQcV5Beb@mdACY0bhEVLVq50w6pu1nZfHh6dzFi3IcjQNFiIhSpr0ct4InZR9xwhL9@TRN3YTp7sb2y7pPTnarwvCCHGm4OmszkvtemcPpD6OT9FMJs2BcwkJKaeiphW4uPbtHduFvs4NOkD3OSbmGdSDUfu7i/qa5VLLTiT/Od5Fr@CiWVkLnBdWmTvKzSdTczirns24hQtiVoJ95BcWhjbs/OO9vH3sffD9mk8u6RjIzXuKYwAHfIeHwRPPHA@A8qeSPKkyEILz5ibX5A1blZFzOo4wVZgZm@XPzfMKcusCVXnnKJHpEM@h@QawLQ4pEXCmc8ykaUoj2Ye3KmLEZv@2GyMYy@lB7lTlWbg1jna757y9I71JyxDVexwJKA5ENPnPWchrUetr3hgUvliyLyDixbqjMMErQyEybjZbT3Ajdcw18ZMlMzUHA2Abke6wcazaFuy6zoGnYptDfhMscxeDvoA16HHsYy9hQxaVhwiAz1DblYu0DCLQ4lEv50NDyOJnjxsK13occKRGIimb0RxbOBGQgstoFc155UAp6WMngRlwKrJrKF9mGFkrUCv4wLyqUh2O99bqwcAGUZtRop85iJ0prm2yLDiiywU8yjTjMRCCcZHUo6ZMdqfQhNRCbbZw928NPXR6SiksvnNRvDOvKOY/QSWCroZzkIvcC@/n2u@ytaQjzLShZRQtLY8DKNZh2Id6QT@odvzm1BEmGFxMnjkmLdpT1s@cmWhZDtCaWw1aEreFQqenJsUDYUCmobAI7AwKIEUT2xzD5ygIoQ7fclg4QGZjrJYgtFr@DKsxSzbjLB4BbvrW6axaJTmNOBBATBmQdAOuRSy0RFGS4vhZBkqCX0trY2PT4rBLsREog5uSiTClnA@cxO0KZwJjARgjApRioQW9Av4K2KOuF3chGMfd4mSDZD1FoCaG0xyCheBQL4ALajUrPLMZ/ViLGA4VQuFolMbk9K@wIAv1uYIREA7R4q7YwSgr3OGEaiGMhqgNk25rYC8fP5K1jQZCAQ800czwNIAmMyMxFwL1bGxBUlKIcizuOMcioSMTlqWrIXuVFxbWUqWaGqsdA9qzYdL1Gs6jmYzSv63yUSydBdeUsujJOiakUp4qVcWo5nlaHRJWw4vaahtPXuGM2r3S6DMNRIwQB0CUHxJjZSAn0H5Ky9ppSVpLbzULqeXKQa8whD5DiJ8ZyUTd0vSfXLpGShLMfAxudAJL1lk9CmVSIj3kD9sIUvJGPDMHVovIrvTmPySEo1iHhJLDczAd8nLkyh1m5cnSZq8KzljgWS37zS3KVXMq4kZe9mcgI530euwsthhORtcGy7w2K5kZl7YA@ofT/gVHgNgtHtJtvyDL2Ey5OmCxZHTKHMdIRPmVreAgMMwEBFfY1IkAsLkN78JijnGhPVcJqxH17OpUjSUFWGYDuPr4HPQw5PLgincXW7Fb5jcSec@xi@kTuJj/ej66Oht5DLMCiwU3DwUxBXhWzQN/rRrlaUfuNgPv4LB5WQgmFwWn60mkx8@fIARB1wXlUQFxAe/IhfxUP0ivMpYZXV1OZbLL8eehxq@bEXC6XTkhClKkl0qhtVuw0/vkZH4cJBf6@uUFgz/4Z9xPyd9x@G@IIjjG/xKuBspG2SXq5K0HF1JP9dKiXQq/Xd/s3gfuztqrP3d7/WT8iI@DvHx0/t9dJ@I2W8WF7/Z2FhZiQEhufvo/dG7arW6shXLHl1k11fiqcW1//h/Li6m02vp5GLdssR66OL6rZBOrQiJv/uL0NHR64ZlASEKeGWYCE685@EnsmyWXbNPcF13GP6T@1Pb55bQ3ex8QktbMF4pk7AJhbKZ0Mm3ofnVtsjEyvrqf/754cegHaykk@cmPO3gx2AuH@ROcMBbxn27CVaCawiWuw@OkuVyGZyr//nfQfzKS8CDIaM1uFWyLq7cKFiJlynK52AlBw4xnYZ0/@8f/SgQrAyDn4KiKAZH9NdAN1z5Z@Izho6ksJoXdP05mrHHa@i7xqVIimL60q1PX3Vj1XrePcAN9cp0n59X7x5XMYcbyPFUuArcanj9/f/x93/89z@nvz@m339A6@i5xecfthiToQfGq1h8PlMPe1Pvx4k4XAmvdQTxNe6ULJgvxxo8Vx4LB32OKTp4d@aQxHv/SrhA0DXxi3Kozva1cV1cBsX8yuHzBypovumloHcxJxmPpF7ibNrPrQzvhbmygH0NXCD4Hdvnl6bBP/zcV/RBj3300/hN4xAujOfNfZAd1uFahD/6h8t7xfsi@TjeBDJ7Lf4W0jcQvAhe1Os7Gv41P@Lf3if8@2jj32kL/44/4t/pJ/w7tvHvyMK//Sb@@WsmEFxbWwtGo8egMjpM@5TrDH6JRMN585g3GAj@Ti8WgOZQj8bv7y8S3w6jpZLzD3pUyXvDi7sgR/X7eHzt20o0ekE5u6g4WVyLrxzmDtnzeoXnmu6JxrdrgD26drG2VtY36ZdoVPCK17@tXKxN4iA09crz51Fsss8BRaV@cREI3mGtlPG2jLeWhfe0ICTp9TNKeOiyC4EgarsFrvQWuAd95wPfAsEPdx/C0fXoekpN3aTEa/F6Xz8c/x8eDiFAGaaudDPVS/XENohMlpLPUqPUaJjq64diG5wy/KX64FRSnWGqm9JSmiiOhhOoHv7vH@r2/qEO2HSIaQ9TNiJOdeDZPTzcB3wdSPsK/pRUKjWETA5TN/CfUlGAkwlBen7biNzB9eH@w@X9ZeCCCR9k0BMSYiiRCiVyoZBSz@aMj0Is1Li8CNVLwaR1eZnkGhRLr5TIhuT9faNRO9hqNJLIU0vR59H4c7jKleia81gPVkrrl8U4VqVbqcHk2vplJRNHdy4KtZRGv@hXXmOM8KwsXgZgSHh@jr/z25tb7iIHui7P6Wrw4PPzJPe6PXeuW7iSNw8gmHAwUEb/if7bh/9l/e@fMRa@qEfgfne/FqYrgn@RyN393b1zr0TCYeclvAZ/6AHvGOXuvoJOAroD10U4Uo/c33M/uIcjaxxhBdNYq1DkMSA02SBP9TJUYgxGT2Fn4e3ycphKRUpN8PGm4KXPtIYTKdHulqUmrrvBiEFcjhBIdqVUWnHcq/lSKe@4xVyuVFr2oFLw4jgBSLakVgkZvRQ0IpgHzv7hFE68kKHeULgtd/CLDeuGAaM/sZD6/NnzajTaitlooH/m8@dLaEkh3NxSLmTBJ5X//BnaYSgCI8MD3VlWLcA4T0ymx@h7kiXZthmGsX/sMoTb3qzLUATD06kUAmN8ll1by61UKrkVcOfykUhJWOI7Y8LdaEGM3C8lBV4MGLOFgk6QmF@NkO99CMNZcI2tV4DFLbzY3X2QqM1WspFwcyRHPA@xUOA@bCUXzkcLzl95McKSlWXm/F1cZKIry6vLz@v1sQaCUqJ0J5XF@/KdVMR5hPtSy7GSi/uSpWfPMgUgSz5Vugw0GlvV02oDPzeCa9QghRl6krwJ4PqjYYYuaNInW6hfYEHql6FQsfSc12s@y4KhkgMXD4HkYvkClTcII0ulgwcShoAV8QaCRXE5nVlMZoff5GopGBEt43VxcZFP56PLINeWC4V6vU6@axTjoj/s1MkWWjl@Ieay9TjqMVfDznLQYOJqJrgcMGin0WqKtXGx1sQJtEXwhCplTVxXt2RVdY0S3@qm2r5V2vJiIHi0V92sncbSa4AyvV3djKVPzjaCIr5mx@8UnMH341p16/AMIhzt1aontRe7b2pnR@CPJkzh6h9J8kBuyLeDwS2@N2S6NhVLurqSDKNhwDXsfP/Ln3z/y//u@1/97Ptf/eT7X/3xr3/xxz@B31/B72f8@bN/W8ji/de/@Fd/@f2f/wo8/wP8/j38/ubXv/iTH/Efvf8t/P4vn9/fOj8fHP8FANfv//oXP/@LX//iD/4Ufv/G@f3p7O8P/2b@749//PAP4/38Lx@H@dm/g9//xnG5sD/7c@6Hzxn4P@dwf/Cn3//R/87//6Pzh85fff9Hf4s35@UnP/v@xz///se/9/2Pf/r9j/95@vs/@V/ElP/2l8BJ//jXv8T/n//1P/77X@L///o//eNf/w//@Pv/Mzn@jDv@n3/zb/n9H37vJ//w43/9D7/3iwfuP3n0/osn@P/in8Dn6fl8Cp6nlOtrfX7xg/Lz21BjnArwAPDWv/z@T/4FsNcf8bf/Ht7g3wv6qffihURpDBqPjj1/ytjnJGh3qeefPVBA@T@iL3izz5PYyDfl@v76F//6L9B7AvZf@DGkxFnYJQT2Uvsptg8vY37Yn2IL@/6XP/r@L/7597/8s@9/@fsodOMrhVg1Fhe/MDAFwOwT4BAw9xQ4ABTXcFV/kS0G0uBYXMOpl4AY/fAByLoILhgoLAeyGXgL1us01ri8SFYuk5cVftXhPZGsoE8ieZnE8EQSxhkN9g2M0fD3/Pky@yYe58@xX0CsEGrIYxT6HhEGdMt8JiWK43P4DQMrBXjDuZUodJlRHhSFoI0oK5fL0cCwDGEECq8YZ8gqeRzp49iwDHgxEo8Ta@RBC2fDDcICMcvRY9ZYLg95xCh6VAgDwwyh17EgpoVovrwFCZaHWwxxIfJo4AM8P5Qr@fKwgui@oywAjugGJAlQZczdsPIdvJcJJ8AHhlvfQVby5Wi0kgefMhWVUos1KE0xS4WjskcZlRv9YQQPj/XnjH0jiHmBD16hZpgDjffoGHqd5nDWIfwyuuwUh/5dJ/2WMT5U@5Dow/14@Dp6U3wHAPDG47ihDH5QjQDwHIKHHFWUkoVHlGMAykWdKRbPgxSWaCBK9RulF0gf8vC0a63ie0F0WJylpSVwrVWEjHAIYx9mXhctWzJxvYV0uiITcgUBvXF/jrx0RKOj5a1luIvwX1ukPbacHMuBpRDqLyHmphGPZvQVPUi5d4tGZVmmnEcJLhAc@3N9nBbNQJFeYZFAmD4tEKEhtmwY8Ny3uhv6EHTmmCDExByfFo84I/B3erFY/k5cWQ3Ak94H@FUDx74@VAN@6S6BjRUJWrmLr1HDBSfoWLlApeIs/DExUDmpnUKE00MmplMJBor23cpqeiW7kk1ncrnsalpcyRVWctl8BoReLpVNp8XCykohX1i9pyw9B8ERKy43s2uVfzZz/Tf/bN413xevQOUtGyZY/D5QGcbjyTTluCxmV0ujMuSDvAIV0h75kGJ0F8f9noFL2l92h1uZIFuBuziy6QJcLLAQYAvgBRegxSUP5qzD7x6WnAVJ/F4MX5QUxCwwQiRwCYzAsQWM6SuAFfcMpM0zkTuzubEzhc5TPKJ4AGlANWhsDzd/2jo71fkmww25FVhzDtdVAgFawbkAotYD@EGGi3pgLemFzse02eOfUdw0ddDJfzjMhqRd86AthR@r8oJ2JLR7ZvUVu/cAxJnRx3M9svlPhqHWb0IGcaaWA2zAzVR1fR7AKjs7eqCU@96RZ1wKpTPPAH68@2Ln1Pc8rVU3dwI5tnF4sDX1yDpAWbZX2z71Xld5qBs166F4V9vbm351HjiuWmTZ1VgM5CPc8Bmji56JpW9dEDHxyJQzdE7JNbbUYTh0zkKbZzmQwJflijTsaANgcRgYJhsya5Q3LsRSsF7Jr6xmV3Opwip7fjDoD5ASrDvI7x6ivBMyq0JRWBfEgrjOzoqLJfPOvpdiLB/Yx71xBZGf8VCswA4MzPr4uQU0xmEH8LBWG/dH4Di8iR9NGxjsQU94oBc6TaXbA@F3q7sAgaYkMfh97QXxZf9lP@5h8zTIbyZEnQOOq4FKh6UCCZq/Sxfy2Xwhk87H8oX8ShbGr9mYmI6Jq/nVQiompsS8mMtnC2Isv1LIrICYhNBsYTUQBHGidJJJ6AVEQaCnorXQ6PEaWo/WE71KIMinP6DrDUvQx0dYUAo2PN9BngmZ/GUKIgv40QrLpi3Ay0pZwC/vpvC7toBaYi0W3N7eTG1vC8IGvuDE5WZKENr4ks2nUqsbgiBTyCbI9LQg6DwOBAGYzV9SqY1NQRhwBHiCWxB6@FLLoT4rCAq@bFa3tzGdK3xJY3wAu@Yh/EV1X1YBTMOXTIYUYkH46KEDuCpPaIVyWsMXTBNDtnnIJoQJwgs3P6kUYDjmcBzDjlvWalUQdvlLtYohL6ngWZ7VV/hSpUsQTHgBbhSELji6pixrgtAEJ/KkILTA1RpJ4IempvGwr2ZLgjDiBEISCcKQoKXWtQCaluOPyezs7Eg9uy13@TUy@bMFWYMQZTiobTdfvGh2u01zVK29OMaQly93pKvRwGx2m060ZgMuHeJAyHV/NH1BHncbDUmdG/IKQrSpkMaoIWPeGtJHyJNzdTGRfuMlhLyEkOGci2ODqw@gTbw2@vDckJoU4l4UQs9hsymUkFHtkSHjhBE2HtpJFetLLVMv4fuwvBgKh2Kji3S9RL6sH47cpUr3GNgJ0yd0UEpG7kYXw3KqDsq3WMJ5q/BiH2VVViguSuvhIbpzIL/E9IoQKS4uD8OXsUZkXUiD@lvEbxHpnRALxcX1QV7IgaBbhicIO5R5w3AqlGIMbrHIxWp9XVhFpML6ely4EPEVYKT4CqaAEnIVVYPSPdDCho6qObDlRiMcvpWl60gEs4vaBOX7/Pw8csd3jo2orEqpEx7GhmWeHTaKlLAwpmwPoJ9KzaBs4yHnQcvWTY64C4QZrqeKVHrITF6AbCSTkTUUTyhQ4Pnh/Nw3M@/N0Ptc/EqwYpx/5EfM5yIJ3JHe0DsN@qAG@@ADROXxHM@N0JlRd4MR6c1WMXCKGiZ9IpSh5YQmflWLTvjC0IWbcKFvYMmgbxYCgYqjcuEh6MT2QMOiJfA7X3bJCTmVh3ZiR8ZtQC3Xb5OfzkzUhvgpTEXX3ICTEWgN/cTuYeJMs6SOXLqLn8fv6ZQxnvPEQ99Km0nlCrikdpgSYlLklvLcqFTKjXJf7hv2CEYopCRXvLjQO7INxiHxxIi7aR56UihKqqShiRPqWJeGwWGg0sZj3RvljbtBsQiw9yW5LJumbgpBodRZ18oDyuCRbOL5jt1D6LJlPEjR6n24rCHcJlDt7j5eMZlW6pYvMN3PeFuLC0I9Hr/4XAdVuJwqjYJS2Ro0yYgGSzVBV8@VhuAnrq6UVCgqPySzRFvlpFKPNcvNb4cls2wMTLlE4J9V6M8aiQa0o4t0qhBLi9BjQU8GQfBbhfcV@InwS8Nvtb64yMJqODVMJcSYKIsxW69pQJxUsYg0AuLSKzylSDS9rIbbOpPW4kRraDwlTBgacI8ZSqwXhljHsqRy8Ej043ouzlbESCm8GClb8seSn/7hSKlTDn8bKX0EMptL4XZiI7K@UmqHN1gjAh7QHcMvzXIrfChABTMWG@UUHxQsWYP@RWoxJ8bu4o34vSpZ9pK4mi5eDJYu4iKUK/W5uya8rwh1IPB9AMYP/rl06MtL4Oc2K977j/vvsZ9RAlVNlaE6xEK65IAEDKeNhwUWxu/W8Q1j4VBoNR0KRUIlgFoEbxIVkTtq0CGQN6FnIkgZ6FmLQiEN4WPRMJMDPvDJiYHgfaCtWAZbKQSCd4H7u/u1iqshvmKjkRSNu6/PGOtGYQicpMW/RCPIFskVT1Ses2q52j2ulhzQ6iYNVJMBdsmPIcaTi1@7xBhdq3zLn5e4vAzJBDhxaD0@uRatJC8DgoBNxFkaCuezET5A/i5ItmHZ5l0HxQQ0@uI@0koqntAnGy7qke8OFPUun4lXaOQE3HJ/H4xC2XCnSSVJlGod0gaPQFDTHSeuFtggY0B8ZrMCjqNlZpwUvl39Nv/t/tnh2eE2e54q5ot5ToZLPrSNiSExtMaegxanHNcCQeOznhW/016WgkUjlFkJZSb08suycwA/jDwQvsClNPjVL2CAXI@Aq1wW18XVomI5K13hojUwZDOyLubSxXRKjAStezwdnF4N0lPMrQbrQY5yZTUCblqjSYvBStLxFlcxVpy/AfNmg1bhczCdygeC@f0PnxlzP7StpMmVTDqZXbpfu4f/yv3F2hq7p/mBe/rHWxJu9xxg4p8e4@sBmHF4/dvGt43id/E1/r8Gt8XNQ55zIQf1EPwAAsGygoFgIQRjmhBLZ/H0YBQkH3QFF6zuLJynxVIdAvCSv5XlZY3@ZGsZ/8bvy5a1Bu/uq4yBLFuBsdFyMpm8jLxOgwpfKOTEdDDwm9krubwQYMsLVRbihth4n4dmWL3DaKGJr@Dh/M7yQnzr5HDzVe0UOz1Zw68Ys83DgwQG4Yd2x6cJW6osmerI@dLuCKGwrzzdPGK6yc62jijOOZ0jJV@axnFSWdptF50PTsVumJjI4FJmNplaSYpZJuaLqdViOsckkEgW2o1wXEsYlVGxNnVjxAde4c0IRV6oIgyG7SkwLLbkIntxtEcxyKTE8sJWbf@QHR7svUu4vtz/dGf3hJ0cbp@eV49rUI792gkTqids90Rg57unO4dnp6x68I5B8HH14HS3doIIkgGUZqgQcoJ5oyC2Zo2sJGqLFg2FJrwtvXUt25P@kmlISbQrPOmt4VeGZPw2x6T/QFNgnOUfZZ1UF7iOxRC91G6bATzAqrTYAo6rFpahF8fzs72Utcqyg7efUmZ2kbVWDkKrrJU60DJrq0xNOX9MXelnjtni4uKlJnhdgb8Y3iDP74VHH8BvnKfd97WFcG6FLcOALr0SGYccHB4tpNy3hfPj0wXRCzveWkh7L7vbCxnvpQZvK97b9vnWQtZ726i@WsiNox1sLqx6b1u1zYW89wZMulAY4zzYWhBTAZdYN6BoLdB3FsPbu3s1tgxAkdJEKE6uoWPKGwgRBuWIWxNBkrPl5dueHqOxQnM0Bd2WvwTtgk9ALaB6doF0rcfYsm7ADRQ/AIZoAU9dl8xuK@ZgRRtc0McE7gILWKAFLBDAL@A5doRji2WWjjAIXujwXRVhbpMxxoQzi06rfmOxNVSnK8AMMTLqRaeWIYbsfHA1sHDvoAx3aAKyQ1uxCVSEnAqmEIngUceDs709nphBWmVYIEjGVcw5OHUDsEER4Y5FB19eObxaqC6QVguOfoEfhQ3cT9RmYLo2kRRQzoWFFiCYpO6NpMYY6lcxXLJHvPjCj1AAMASDOwUufsYzHG5hWbuy3aIMRZCYtcNtXkJc9C@zyVqOMEyUKEXB/HDG58/Mfbu0J1/NyVctxHE7yHm2OD6e0zLCRtBvwT1cSxBkSIBiLiDHRKMQG4pDYb5yLQDR4cftDri5rEBCqRB79ozysQZvhRAlgfGilCKLIwgicAhG5ENkXtYWKbuRheQybsehzTlkNxb7EW7mtznybKaAZJ3O6FSteq3Qq84FDUaZpSmB7AR12ljX4M6kG/CO4hE4Ocaa0ExizA0UcxiII7IYk2OsA95TMrWhaMC5sjmWiS4rQGOk2j/Y4jXEDQSRP/egEoPcK1KFgbB4hs2XGH1hoWnCoLvkQoE8JCjgW2SaMBKCwz0e73iLoi3z9oJsibGfEnN3u@jyEY8N7OBwGpEVbTpwXnGKS56VMdAMfgcZtt8yoOcsyZFFow6Ex2UOWG0SLh7ncPcuX36hELXpUix@dSlQLD9YitoTi/HblQK6tTGLQClAxIcBbxSg6TZZm@l5KKAvJBRUmh@GAjrQMS9BG59A8IT40OWO48e/Pj500sXppgztFmqQSwUeZfK1NfnannzF5gs@EoPhQXqFfWZNdIk5cOHZfpYHR5vLysmInclXmrApM9mN0/EkME8BeA5FJQdDBpwVxihBEhZ@kkTq44exyqy63dg9qJ1OhiK@hNVwMt6zdU2lNCKTYE6GMNwK40vEy1G4g0Tg@mb4iKcRI3o2Tk6Pa9X9GOQvwtbGLWBaB4Cb0xImSnDvpgC@mtyC/rgdY@GTKluOsGeYsxhzpg3w5clJqLolA6oHU2wPjDQlleIg3vtkSwpiiwzMSUoIs3CEfb68hC41tcrEvvE5089oq5k2G2VWUdnleDwdxJHyroA54E2TKxsI2eb2J4tzE7tKpdiKmWG23AONe5gyZ/FTue6xb6Nu0T2BbOg0KLNKDA98o2xx7LVAvzip2jyuRVLfiHyAvtiMwQ@7c5rki5J@juxJoa6CxfPSlr82L1/SaCfzEud5WaNEZ/PwG2diFIZLgalT5mT2RjdsQ8KD2E7gIU2nHqGXGQjwGRef9bOwjh8jsiNFslqDMqXRQMOzjUbYktUOMKs@MFvQ5aO6bDlgeGFoggdSQ0LHZKBDHtSfJgPaCh6cRrOe0OtMIUS7JOCNthbDlGIg4OXMsmWDcuXLBs6Y4Ve6/QnCAHviHaoVDzT6chwpOlrxtoTtwUV2MWGwiuMYWL3YHG8Qz7O@HpvOCfPYZk4Y2iWcF8U9aD8n7GrQn5cDEAwPhDhHZeeEaPrhvAjc3tM4oH7hI@CFn8D1ejgyv@qhXU3WuM9gF9H/1BzIjvWp3UMfC4Jy6XCgr66DWzIwbUvBTzxMI/IO60PM8DDisxvgsVVkzEmS1VKUafQuJgcRHXylrxiwYbHVA6zfiOl8JOZD6MPY5mZuH8LJfEghh3OQBNkJ8b47F2p5qJEFp/GO4yfQ7IXWhuHdOIJuPAKPoWNYrHwXeAEtlnkhHjPPaXJjdMVZxiF/nH7H6hcnbLs9BO0WQoz4CfrbJh//2uTjvvSxTf6gpMvsYjIf9ajvvQge4zK6DfwHJeTmejK1yFeV2M81snz9APuiDR5fMtz2xmSyHhpHAnk85RaF0KPHE4UE4vIj@gr5QtXnWAaYF3vc/yyXWVz04nCJN24NNB/ty3wArYY0Gmhut9EgO4uNBs4sNRoCT4E6Xuzw/J2u09h4WAK01IZOoWEhLgkxIR6vnmzu7sYVTYhxq/llwbJ1U26guTQhhgvEZYEEVgNherJqlAVnT59kMYotPJxG1ZcGFPDLiRAQT2VXo0TGdnS/nFzLXyT9CUXSpxIb2/Z8QmrHlBqaMXgsJZMbyXMT2iQ7bmgYz5QVFDT8ewDOJ@7R4MmEnQ2c0neywNO1aKbPQusmPEv0aKCfU9doJmRPoVE1zfYJrt0fYcZMj9PacaoHEYw5lXOfcERfDWNkA64tO3oWTQ8lhLH9TydjCaekPn53FTRuNmXcoU3aAnLyG3PnJi2cxpzK6liw6AYW/kJAU0FQAUe6AXfPXBC4PYNB4EaTQejlijpwo70gjNFxHI7pIHCR8SB4AnsLY1ulfWmo9Ac4ceM3SOFocuNsYZePJaFenwInpR@nKEIkVDT6HHbwRqJCUYCiW2SoaNpYEcLPs1cUqQdmhSxZ18Zs@lSHeUjnWkCKxH4HleRTxFA0W05uIG5MYAJXQiiuWKzD4NPHO66IQfV5yk/ns56ICEoS8@KP@yufvaPyxPACKQKDB56ZcQQ@y@T/Oicp95Gip4KMa8wPxRW3OfnGLbkPZtyPwVXUIoFHRlL/vxkn@avkv9Ch0v/3g6KZoc8/8VDmkSHMV49WfofDgv@q0P9Xhf4HKPS/M23@AZV8GuVsi59S17@ohn@9@kUybwTdhtm9wam39A/Rw35HisDqV@kBbq4vxMd0gS/3zy6atL9b/4G9dOA3ydN27nxbr1arp33RPH5R7VZ71WM0LbWR2oueX61sbN1uvNhoV7e2ui@7mwfy63x1Zc949Tb/7kXn00cZtPedw5fvP6lGqxd4e2zcnstHtxk5b1UHg4@7OyN7Z@Osv3mSfbd6m6qp2c6G/HFLtbb2T9@@On2RPYnefnx59PJTP9W3jjopqdDP7Ozn3myOzrVA9kY5a2/vKYf9k3btLN3f21LebUc3U3snhddiaq92@z6zeRvNppK7xqvDF8dnV83ae/V4d@9de/OjLuU@Xt8au8l2obN5dfwmcJh5Le58PDzs1tKFFzvJ262O0U6ld1Qze/X2@Gjj7N1O75VU629nzwpvr0ZHud7r1zf2QbS7cp4b7FsrUa36@nX6lfbi5qZ2HGhK@qmZkc/116Jxe3ukF/qr8quDnW7/tSlqycPsm@hJ//R2q7ahflwdZs7enb@@XTl5N9h//fL9YUo5OWnWpJzRbKdPrk5XAq1@Zjd6c1Y7y0sv2uev@ze7O9l3W8n9nnxQbR@p1y@6O@/1k6O93WrGGmji3uaN@u5F72r/emtzV9WPrlWtupLMqqftd4eHgbOXSnNL3nlrvaxe9d4lsxvXK@@ibePF6dWn3vXLjZOzw3x6eDRK6ZvWcXOnM9w6zqXzyZb68fhTR98Xz15HczdXL9PKu@onO5D5NMoW9tR3cl97GW113w8/qsnomShuvt/99O7dyc6N2axqZx/fbB9fmftt7dA6TB2/fLXfVK/z9pXxXjs5EVupF/L1fjQlBYZnOxbUkXwqZVdP@3uvjeGW/vF4972V@xS9Ob/OyFvXx2@qH49TzVvNeKuZe0p/M9U@lKpvdLs2GL5oFW7OrnfUvY@H1rvAfk3MZrf1jrXRebNSeJt8Ee1cv3i7IZ4MUwfacWclZx68eX2uKLXe27NPx63s9hsj37e17utPZ/1atLY37H2S86mmevLuWgucZU@Oj9K32iulb2/vHO/n7MPU3puj9s5IrL6WxVttdXOU3Rqaucz51lvz3fWOZiTfKR8HRyn5Jtp@Z9grr5Vmp/VGafVfBU5e9s4Ojt7c7mZz5ou@pmwc5VMHezubB932yqvR7v6gtte8ar/YfSu/NU5z1@naxnlu6@1Jxj69fmUXWjf9zFE@eqr27e5ZNPBy0BusHp2bH98M369U@005c6y@00erYn/zpZEevqnWDj91r48M/UDcTo@SZ3v6tZr6dHr7acfKVUfR/PDM7uv2qTjMiq8DmdtPhv3SePn65HDj5eH7l9KKopxLVydv2qnMWT6p9MzMbi73Qqxtd/of@wVZ/LS1n5Ey/V7U2rtOtjfbZ2/Or9Wr/qv@VSuQL1itjd33A0mvNdNi6t1Gp5aV9zb2TkX5rPvqZGXrIHX0tn109nF42t58Ozh7c6ikalcvC3vdlbfHbwqvVt@fWqfSuf72lXkQGOYzuiXmCtnbzEkhf9gzTzLnVwX7/aur3IZ63hRf7qb78rZivs2P8tfGp95t9/ZETjW7L7Y@SsedGkjSs6OUlB1cHwxPApk3p/2bVWMj@u669eqtJqr5c2U1efrxqnDd67263WqtnFc/fZSyL67kwsl2sqluZ19EjzdfH111t84/5VfaqY29N9LbYa1nvwu83lG2rgrn14fDkfh6@2TUr6Y0NXtzcp69OdU3Ts53TvK9/abZae5c9UA29EdnV7eDmx15tTe8zb/qXb2RUntv85uatXKUCryUd/vt49NXb6vRTlou2DeH7w6M8/z5MLuf188L@mFeeVXtvBi@PuzUUquGcn46PKv1khubSj8PMuVIPTM3D1/vvD9/aaQCaS238WlTz65@jN4M3@XOk0fRvcG71mm6f26aO28Vc/vtzdHbVyfV3ehuc/Ti6Fo6fFfLnhxsblovo9tKTh7tZG6t6mZG7egBq78xPBiaRiHz/nqvCz2B3i60X5xmzjWrWu3c7uZPatXqC6u5@1IaDl90VqGPwKt2/kYvB37DzQYGuMVA/pC4SZJA3@o29SHIS35EMEDnvAJ0zivAT3bRZmm@Efk3yeXAqf9UA31bmk/wDJqgrLG2jspDgu16tn3x0x4x1tchuoKulm7QE9E6RzfaOOBT4U7zVXgIkb6MKQ8NVVfwq0n4BQcck5rjj9glAoca649wvGnLfX7WQsEPHzmmeOmjD/z7UmQKNLDQajH3@6EJMjTrfU30AygQhtaNk2XhLovHWx1V6lrgUNvk@hA48SzfYwqqIuHkByYh7jUkMZV1tqbSN/8wc6f4vaaDF0zV@Scl3BGHBMrEiEyy4CQVmWWR8RuDlnIjqyP6RojcTgT4js8n7YL0@@FG70k/Moc6tTcU1A3ZnNoAavCI7kprcvk5Wst5vpx0llhRGWpIZlOx8QvWDX5qosFTdPe8GZN7D@l0sLNAyxUj1GzIkDB39qUhvk3FQorRhvPxYT3cTwcpgorq7jZcXjYIJe27YvzFh3nZeBi30u/@rlBP4G4r8gReHWg1AFrRgvTMmv03Fm1y9IBKAb5YX3u7e9pwPiTDtxhOHJB6YMelj8ol980o8RL48u/kfHZbJu4wgOzjtCO3ww1FvdE5Lwu07xG3R0Jt4wh7vNsyAVxDOw0Qm0G7US5W6nwHYYq27rkE9@I845zwzJerZ2OCLjgbKjweeGI8vkGTg8yWFxF3TFkmANrN6R4Smdrs9zvmvQdqpqlK2jW6SnyrLIwXzJavsugTGb5y4FSWVxZn/yQ/GwflhqjeNthxRgXTqxYCcDbEutV8pmFzpv32GIfXsJc0zo9hGt6oS1X1VngcvOxuueFli7gpcfippA5xJrGDO2t1c8QTwumZcKkEILhPh2SCrLm7VX2lLo@pgehoU48vF8C3JdcLTRHI43zG2OO55UktEjvQDqD5WeWbgRDqwstWnSf1sCwEekf8hZmIOiaOu4UInMllZusGEKHjcBx0Y8QjfHfqDFX4Ti@Pixin00WqDv9s3f9S5Bt3sUHJOO2JIiSCzRhH6FOZ8zKNoBWv6WBSY9ajisId3FiFCvEiU2CEj/5MiUYn6smH/EJBuoksStQOzwkFMeSVyCG9Q3uCoT1xUBt8Ky7r8B1cnNaBKRKtQUKfP3sNBl49bjxyD2MCS/DDljqzkME5Z/K27BC05L67jdBzU8iYKJ5UvZ/dS0@HUGEArt8aylBWwyAwG/iBHIOBl7NlyTC4gyC87UvgjZVNeXfk1eJiGGJdEFwyX2fPWFhcWwuvxsPk9U0@EvEaoxM97YvuiwxCulJh4fRyOONGXsHIgDIziWBlPoI0R7CyHBZdBGkHgZgFDFzFICTfsDzn2knEeR9iD299EgY/szMn9eV0VKyvreVxj6fPcypyen7WlzPRNETmqBeikyEcLQ/w@dcnSwTIM2lfP@JDsRLNAAqedHQyYJzqVICXqD/Nlfrczul3pry45zTczoei49c@ZfMij@VFTuWb0g0GbsM2HU/84ppB310b@3GWXkY2Bx2BmiSk1pPx0FSMf3fP6bSAfqWpXtF3OIIgUAwQEVw8SoxdPdbXNb@@s0PgDk3w8TLHmBhjeRiGgEQBiZGHyCBCiAZKt9HqGx4cdMX5CN/xzTswSuQAV5zx/ADUE6r9bkokxjj5cIUb8DnfPaM@hNM3DBEae7sb@HhTO8Yds7sHL6AKF7AcMTa@u8Vc5Bi9Im5KGv8Wi2IrkAWQbXxA45SVV9Vk@ujppu9gc5E78NPYeUQqHUIwHtnRDokvFLuh6A42TkqXj2Sb6EifBvMA8pESjDPYrcwkFckx4p80zvMviNGhN4pNpAKHF9HJIFIIaXZ6XD042T483ifKHTWqe0c7VcQMA8yWZLYZfeMGG4imySrvVD16BrD77eKn2LFMUtP9IAv/SD3C8o8lcuIBYINCGuQ7nSMsL2f6GXjuPS8CSRQPGpSKRls25uDGvasemFMYaw5CXos8105X6ORpXk9IHd5sT@jK0QpKOqKlLltayAbGpm/@SBqXJ0kX3waMMumDidRyUY/qEr@Y/AtxmTR9Nhr5yBoYuDostwU/@aVWS7bI@sGY@oBSVjuUiCNZfIQCn/mlH8sPfjbF63sdHPTVTOp0U57eO1ZzJ5VF0B457X6QjutTkDgWV0e6c9VKUouclPlXrCdUR2VSZXwoMZ7aFU/tClLjApddTStkSv3iakIRm0cexSXPFdeNXc2MqyfeVnKquQ40equHBopoLoRLHaowrCayxqGPJmTdM7fKnrmteNwS5yt3jytlDmEnNTKnwxn3n86Aud0GsoVn5jbo5AqNvgYm1j9/0eRbfKGekh90cocYBE@c0gB12oVzxSeeoXqQMxATSEM6LXPhJFenTsXDF3YQsribn4hP16BTmM6sgKKBtBgfTnPKSqqkbjkDRZ8nilWnFzbbbiMnyHFnZranD3QhEPryA4fjUwn8GB9PKI9O@uJmmVAjh4x1Vgrgumo8DhEifF6DdBoQt1gGyp5izy9GfrYYTuFcnUzhJ2BQ1DlukYsCBP0M4x7wdRMvzS23rxzuYTiMHPEVLFVyTlC4J3rPjlhGzGR8x38Pzw9YLjc@HYxWz9hKOjU@coz2z1iuEPhB82Tj@QTOj9hwnApFtkKewaE76IKyqkIj5o@2gl0/5o0Pi4f8MSp5ytUyH8Fajjh2ugaL9QcWTlHiN@txvdZm4lBMBBZAKNIcsPMxULfzBsDuQDIlzZb5GUsU5M7KLiZIEVGHlU0oVxNaBm4bQ4mPn7KHbsGU@QQw@LT1Fm2SRBwUD2p60KfdSDFUGG5kE80AKLZz0H@BZI7DDlw0VDgTuJ6ucKi4vMFJ6IgEatE4ycLJSN0yUo9PvTiuNKkrp3spyuXpnkhdmvtdYcwAkddhFaIxdwcWHALPdDM0Hl92Pq7mNkkPeCz6500NznYyfHDqjsMdNLyPmR35K/U5kzHEXS1/HzR0NjERKipTPeKegSMJ4B6BarnzEByIHsM6dU@Ei49GkYIwfmkrfC6ckYwgLYJ6KepSTOQ63KXj2L2j4AXvy@rEz2VofRFnZ8DIOTDnHY90IJDlIxzCORs5DYHtk0MM/TggF7yhLifH@w@GiMM774bimzjEHYWjO@KMCxABH9eS2sXzz8@kzS@F00YpUX4kbTqnFBTxteX5YLzIDhiWzgcGmSJ55BbKBTs7Gp97cwEp9zQh9VjmJ1J7auad5GaAJijxxKx7hLh35urmIYXIff1G5otUzrYaR8301Q9XkqASHUYgnqV270xVODRwpQLPXdMXg@vMbhxXklCIc@h3VuQ4UJ5jOe0eB3YFujfNOT7XO6@gnJPdorrFpBqkr5urikFd42RZnWbhL2tcnC3sqq@w7injicI6kdxyztp30MDRUfVbbn8BOxTBObksfNOOsW/auBji@Pj7KJca8@Tf5FlnX4P8tjxukV75vLzSoVnvhbdVZ@0QRbuf3zEe4k25jRw/b01dgIjgulZyN9fzWAsLjjoDSs9EvHTEmXb22NlF0emAvKat@mjndi/tYhpzDGEps@84HuqCPsnmBLAL9pnkPGYg4sF2FCipD9bHRY5knmikLndgQDTq9Gflidng8QHqBxnRj8WRnb4jyo/GJ5kym4sRhvFucj4ON4rT3Y/bf8mfkdGDGUFy0BqR09d5a0bcJML9b7syOtbdDEdzA73LSMPto6OIOfpbNuXqAWFjrC94owM@HvDrBo6i7SqDOLEFCjyMjfnR6BiD1B@EH1sY@cgX@PBoHsQkCyD@aGRqwi@QeA7TvmGR4RvEzGaTaocoavA6mcw3VSRNhHjYeTGeGReILJmO4zIgd0bFmVJNoGN0yJlm40rc@AepsmijnMapfusfWPHLWHhcshyPsww8HOzudiAUSt9QZX5yR9xrVA93PdNWrGfbRjGZlC0dvayEbnaTt8q1kuSAgRPHbFVcHmA7RyNVPKRRO4OuDA1O2Ql2IvPNCqj3olr2gYaT8iDyASOhBSwNgDsd0Hi1lozfdLFvcf@Ag8BK@DMLwZIFeriusZGuN8e5l5yTOTwDMcq7BZnvAmEGzQRkINmSbEseyUmMmGyqcOtLaG06CUPyJJYweajJexD7BJqEnLiSbqTAli9jdHJ6KlUySBeI49wRhdj4OXTaPYJzCDbui2RNHerG25/qDBLIoKSuqSOmoQmALmC6QWiQKpAUct4tFJN23DqLOrTlQaZxxEqqkCNhbzk9HMXD/juRgLBsJMA/5VvE8x2WjuxiyrQ3laJP7GmZ2pPBG@bkJgo@zp/0a6Fxri/v0/C2eCSTvri69pR9H/P2eJD9LyD7Qzs/kkmcHjVUacSEW4nsfLPNldVUrohjLaWrERtia0EjOj6NXR4a@EFc3BiA/bgbV5VvZJVlsBrfKNYAAE/sARQpEDRMqduXXMBwpsgwGZ@NLhpfT5zoHwfpujrp08FzE2w8osaTaYyJY2x0gsvpVZCYjrfTL8gRkFpwW8ctz7pusCI42nJz0KXOAM9luTHwdJQUa2IEKVIJNyPr8CzCE7JOFqShHWPjL3v2q3A/ka6wC2jmdeYuUAilAJUCmn6Z577kxseeA8F8KzrQYfNVDegRllnDGYzyWQKAxj4szOEsPu9Ji@cuSFvfPcRZG0qQby52Q7CIhmP28cE9JcvMt6cERALam0LGJBNYyaQ7MxKq4qeN3ZeNEA@lWaMwd4@niHivt@yRw92/0OG7T9bIJhgjc55EzkjJ3VUvlti9C4h7QFDDwZ0l8ZC7cwA1TBPXZsY7UoD0gjsKewytLwOZL0BSxSGbYb/kKwbf4F3ns12OCjIdLNbdNSzwL6dKLjX4l9C9@h8vZj3jtblABV@k76rfMUedFlp8IYZWSZwFpom8Yufl8AhxB8fldPFhzg/kMckNzmwiTZrGvAlVnlE@5wrCAnXOOHUpMTZkXZx958OnGBs5r2i7PsANVKdio7JY8qxYy9qgf4eDkRiPMjBiCHzPZJD2pQDenRGdyRP3Wjf0EiTWUZAHSFCg14Xrj1Mbd6kYE@9LlHKLvnDGRTzoEbO8P3cv1qWG@IoXMBSh/zrvJorftIUYTw@XDMghuo50PTZOjRPRy/VwpF@Hh7ERiA6G55EqzqgD3c7kPL2OfEFko8RZp3EEDM7DNiRcd2wg7cKuBTLWGJZhgNQYlXEOj9v/QoWXNwsyIIPwRQaA8TgCwgiVucouhROZQfQNo1EMh0HdZPjAKOIo240/E461R/h5fD/@@7GRPKJDYxhrjCLuvhSI0RgtEwm87Sn3M8Wl7P0W5Z3J71R5Z@jhlfcBenjlnaXnDyqvN2P8lgoCXQw9cIyDQ/Z1GFEDtOfJ5ynWGXqmxj3U1rvp2AMDP0o0FZu@KTEbWzcM3UJz5vNzwNOckwkK9/lDmus8jSK4YYCc5NNHYj4FTQ@/DmAFeBM3ddQXw@TGL1Xy/gv0SZXPbTt9NHkg5gLN6Huv8al3SCDidCV@L1ckeuXDpLhM5eoEqG3XtL@4zHxJlbyMU0H5GIxRZK/0EcZffTh8Rafti5AbNwoSKsLmRRmg3oHxpqOg3/woDtUd@TgZC6nO5sZyKxFjO7srXU2IxI6wy0dJY61b8K01NUg6A7v69AlvHOvN9w6jLoPzyqCZ3lDU7aVhKLbbodm2Tb4Rmx05s1N47AlUeLtn6oNuj6GhKNQBEZZvKe/oqN2jdglaPX6edIC2aorutrjwuPje/HGSnRkMBvl0fh5b7v4R20TFvznCuWQ@FxD2dRPODquFBVd3WhhPaS@QpPeA63yij884jJOnOvNlYAv5AbKwjzNxkPwxsdOchN1OLC56Gogg2Tba10fNWuFFwOKPoxm4DDOOiBqAa@OLlJUFD3R@Zjkb@3JLufNndw9YZV5uU3MzScdQpzPZlHGqL/VI5vgs4vTcDWQHU8fcbMn/BPXnpcpXr2Hc/wXWhERdrowRnAyDXNwcDcoOHs3roy1ytKzBORVG4IDyQDdxbDiKzcV8i/Nx1LqkWxh70VAZ4aIJJzs9GM/e4EajubFpxa0nQVXR0QFEBDkg1YqvneF6GX4ADmPv03DUi8wHwBapcmh3lmdDb@Eqsxt5lhKm/v@2923LcSTXgc/sr0g2ONPV6DsIckA0CwOSADXYJQkuCGqkADFQX6qBIhtdra5qontAKNZ739gNR9iWZVvrS@yu5d2wX3cdvkTsPvh99A/@Av@BfG6ZlVVdBYDUaBR2DBUadGWePHk7mXlO5rn0PK8fIsvaQVqhdjpo3iDLVb8S9v3OMUqIIKnrrVc3h@6jSVo88XtslfHoOTZl4v1w6k9Y2MbW1GEuSe8HSOHRidd7Q7AY7ijGXvNHNRi2UVQLBir84bQzwSuHYKIqpbAgezyfNHuiiZPmo2SDaieAifLcRSbEAkb2E11BpshK39fhVY3e80hZB6NylEKJiSF3Rji29t0P3prUFexX5kIGjuehWOj6IeGxxO@qGkyHuBcH4zrm4U6Y7Kz9hYxl96bLTgwT3bQ@EkC8sSZzLYyihjIxGBw6xuUk5p3mavB7C9BYVQ5wjaGNjGWNrxk0GMrEuCWed8goKL6/gGy6P3eQ3kINM0Bdi4knIgSWaZarVMkiWjqKF7GOglHNxsxgi4gBDsHK150/9xuaP4UM0Aj3Hthg0Pwdbxh7HbyspKaL9AkrnXqJhCxdgX3gdDqMOiMvmIbD@a@aEAo3KK6n8M6QNKfP78tnkh1HMYylswYGA1A7jV1Sd0PdBBTUYfNeebKOOcV92Wpw4k4DOWfVUMxgwqoO1IPPRM4@5j2RPDwctU5AKgddJuBND6oJRGTjVWW1Adg6yVxsFNWpnFaw6/SiKW2iJwEqV6BO6RTvg1DHY4ImYjQluGFjXxB5MPYmXBlQ2zyYKn0@A73Grj5hg4x9bfpQqRx9hB/3ZuwW0j0fJIAHcVuoUOXw2LPKwPYLDQdwujuCduvjrevJHQUebvy6hVE7sQaqFv4ibp9t4OIKP7g2foXDO1@sEnGnyjXRrQAsNuuWjPXsnZsi35e1oJ/SfyKWWd91aVgmKNHtx5cE0qpYvJbTAqzfJkULx3dRU@M@WljAugTQA//wpotvLay1QXdnOItnQCBeZ9I7gS7BfPlIMNGExqnv92nYQIbDa2/jyjxUgB6jGZWZgR5NT7vokmZA42XMNOndAy/JAcSJUZep5tj00qcdzq8APb9CVU@6P@6XzdriqkguQeEHAM09Ep6g0ia6v5SBwe9Ys8mMzsCRT7wKWcFhwe8DSUQ3JeKPfiFr5VB7rjci30o7jbF1CcZyfHmWMgnDC6/IUnE6CyZv@OUIr91o5486Pt1741sgKyxjIX2jh4/8YZzHLxn6ci4Oa0LrGQ@Wk0509SWvpqYINsUhG/Sw4VQ8wPyG146Vlo02cpNpC7awHt9ANSQLNaO4LL9c8sZuiEe/ufIdItsGNW3TLRlr114KPNdylcl2bZPhQLirBG0IpFAEQuuW4/W7XEnqOmqEhqC48SzjUOMrrgZri7lTzU65QPGf26mHT2jFG2009Wpk@nBdpo64DqMk3LNUdZe1eQPrkyWGnyLsuiaAw4eNG@0YfJ3aVjPR7yJLqxlreN1Iyd@Ke3yALOmNG/P3GR0aC6MmHt/JF4maZRmQ3GGUAVeYNlJSnt4YB7z0M0xVRMmTwx3A8a4wmIKYb8CnfRkeRmXzXC8LNIzqYUS0Y530Nd59gL6z1l1nGAbiyowOVi4U0nvh@73E6BXI1cu6604H2BR86YcysYHKonXKzYHZckg1lx/8eaQInPQOp4iD13/Z0hbUDvXZagWgyGRFXvil4IG@E0f0okY9kDsy7oFaPpJqpQ/ahRF2gh68LXc2JFV9Z@Idw589H1vUD0vIL5mX73phiy8Tn@/uPNvf3jva2/7u9t6LbSpJivzGoHg6btBNWXiGzr1HgrcUJhziFD6f@HCO44lDcZZQAn/RC6JIPQZx1wNx/E0HSnamXiH3zX3lSX7ey9CbrHP5fWbmyfieNI1DH02EpqiqBP07YwGcn4edsMzED2cgOaRCrdchejLguFAF3DNhM@cc3D9xJXUDiiNNEGLZgEdKMIjOkAMUaSL5xgwnzbAPq9mri46thsYrh9hfgnGIgAwA5KPW7bxO0czttQoD7wHPiWwktpWjEYPs/aipnnO1W1St2uJ@IQ/ZGQaj44J4T7BaQJwbHFpVjJW@roeYjIKgCtRbQE@BONLcI@5QA@WDRqvebHx9Lg3iR@xfk7eCDzDJ/0A770U7/cz4SVlm@zoGgMXjXKRs6BJhkzIt6LKjNSUN6lIVrUhFH2ZOnm9NLuhv/5otyHMMyKV1q9@M0fjXa899bTPrX9rHwjdvhpNJwAmrHE2@mSqmF1@fwc4/FauR9zMXucqK4lvTiWzTCQmo9j7GE6XlEmkfI@exs8sX9njVZK5/Qq3dLeGMUjyZ3rUSirYmgk1SaT6ORyOayNdTok9o0CfUyn9l6vD5fc2wBYi7m612/B69towjEh1tvpcmvAnUc4WKu62tf5Fov67XVttHlfbJHHnP@CIN15w0N6kiTbvNu3cqoQbOli6s40vkLxrmxrxFO5W3LuO0MrqcHfrOjEum1N/5UjCjtAnyFkmMLA6vlQwxJ9Rq2yQKXLOdUIgXOaqscV0sjl9KbT0ewfiylJyI2Zf40lZnGccGA1HR2YC2B@X0HCVQxpexeSiTU6PnIq8yWWgLNiHmBf6fi7WVIUE28PjWyOrXaGT1rdXIt1Yj31qNXGY1snSzMQ0nja4/agBrNlS1M@D@C0uwoLZ21eefPdhX@59tq8cvH/1L9f3dl@rzB88gZVc9f/nwyc4jBf/ffvZiW1EB8@@73gRV7hVM/ZbX8@h2fqXZXFWEeSFA@ap60TlVnwU97y0Qz/2wc7p5wh/1kRdtcKntt95kHvBz0BiVWSKxmqC7In5r0jdOaHHdBUo@xXdE7csT20jePEO@WSLbCwqHbgy4@W2PeBDS46JnJWO0AfABpAKaDj/Jku40Pq0T09KvKxk48@@9RxCYwqcv1INnWxjpc2tnf2f32Qv1eHcPPp9/H93sqK0ddBvz8CVmEeDT3a2dxzuPHlACN6BZV3i3RgbrlzWhjuA0Kr03gymGBxuiVChfCa/eS4XCKNBWEaEqTUex@54@kBS@u7Oz0za5aHduPdj7zneRq/F@qIpFDHJpOVQXC4RbTTQagdokinabnakja1lr8YZ0Ole3MLtdoDsg@l1VGnmZ3ol9TxUf4TUiPkhT3Gxm2DRqqOgm4EZU2hGsqygCQ6lUvU8oN6A2uj3QteHF6kB/YNFNccyKcuSS9tIaElIMzrgz6nEYXZ0AdM9a3VRtNGEAvBCSBAbAOxhMiDpvvB28JFF3BGIaoeAPCXc54fXp@PEZco1o4CoJDzkQyJq0ieeNphQDHHX8Ec9jwqyJdweKkUJFQoJHJznDob5yJZU44P/ljQ1fZQGyCLvgAFa2FiriZzegBtjbTzqDKFSOW8bbYBBBvJHPmlrHww6Ie3QvPEGDpbeoRkDVrrn4b0M7qtcMJwXi1CJMd66S7TDltuTg965bDko@XKgR9fao06gwJfGfrmzAw4UGfAgaQFSz9wt0KzSOiLElNMFASNkJA6BIEPnUj5JRjYL@tOclCois47z2v/yyLINcjYtYKj7UOqNhh6Ee8CHkDH1QkZsLEGJIU/IEX6N4Dp1kD@K34VNUhphgA3@gB1dqs4UHXaNo4kilyM/n1NrtkDHclbUSxbNusNm@xsZnFD1/h2yWR88kXRSTjTQXoj9nVGJAz04TdPMyUKhYNI@oJRzcoRDvHT9SYePgizV3Y@vhq9qPflA9bDSOeVvo9PnxgpUS@ZmFRHJYHkZ3krQB9UoTpIVw2sXSWp@Rd0tc5RoZMC4nPjDfm0dtk8fXqovpI4qXlUynxHfvXC5VI3sTIiGMJBPvblV1oKusUplDVRYE8d4JjUXPujqlSjjNfr2Jce1xFtowIiPcR0i9xg6rRvo1lrdrfNCDnaUgfBpPt8Ff1rHIhaLon2PPR@ML56Fb2Sg3NBQtJjOcjt6iqxpzqyy9usDppfNqAd3W5ehg/74@urVLW8fHw3th27oU23u1rVbJx8XHkoXr@mh/dAlaPtw@CC30vZqPmA/JRWyG0g1xVm8taZq/osYfLMwdrT1Ag2cvRlQ1SK3apqMheohz@FIcmkYFyjaamCF6sb@1vbenitt4y7YOZWHf64x6ZF@K2yDivqk9HbEdMm12dcM0mTBBhnnSKRdsXpqs9rLFnDl4OVuF8CBVGQ@zWZiovSCZzMQ6gk8WYiHQ8Jo3RD1yydad6z0oPBDEFweoCaXiSbM6WMjs5hIfPuxknzaZeNyqzBuHb/yxYWa8mTjroqvqydxGpBlhPA46x/jynT1/nzN/vK7rYQbL@@GUOoxK@D30l69eQMVjfCmuJ2fwkmnRU0o6K0SlS3rsyCwvyWH/8gRlYrFfCC9sbevCHEvTmD@@ZUWyI/50E9/555LZO5X7Tr3FU8p9e0LL8aHnJI8gYDJBDFabNlVA8cMLOcJoNMw56RqG3F5rt6g1B7qVFM1McLfzgT4CDv7O3fT2kK4KdttLq6p9PVXxKZGoyYq7tViDzgTMd@/cuX0V7nQvdPHaL4ubz5D0/hmdjt92LJThPCRVIaDcnWdVnR8TwCVD54IU2Hf0gkkVBFYn40xJ9J0OI7t90JazCdriQWN2X@5X8b4oXWtZzVJty8bOJ5KNnUAW@mAtYdNRXjULo39xeXUPKajbFfXdfP/6eLEhEN6HX/yCw2TuBWPcKoERnxyxV1QQyddD1IqLsAQHHzSefq0YmJs6juUBx5vb5BdutJHmGjej4A3q9evImRLbrIjPUPXTzvj8HV5wvaMrU85DmwAp61fV5mvWUeHImpv9gJQIBiaU5Sa3MpkG2/zbIzv45jqqD1IeA1gPmK4ZwNLHJQVyzzreKuhQk6UKpwF/YpJqnAS0GqHsYdKXOR3tEvzxcG7SG5ze9zDwnEm9L1jOOibiZWlDINMRMktFAaa7Wn8wP6JhN9mfcjawMSbpI2kMyJbDwKTe5FTUqdJJB1J2GicdchJIUiZpSaDwYPIjm5ZCz3tzRJMs0eYAYamqRv7wsC76U586IjuWxYQj4omE8t6oX6BJoZinBpU@EjbRtayQ0MGmf1gnBUrZgFAmiyeWF9KmHxewgSHdCn3JRMXFqAH4X2mENNUmXqz5YPM1UvjEC3tTT23PUMbXsRE1VZJjkCW1/WxL7T5We7vPt5OoscVHyKNQKa2wR6GYpWHUHb1kqzDhwTQ6OeJE/ZnOPfM4V6PgbwM0CiYWEH@mc3UFhOIQl6U6f9d/pw7g8B6bSXH65UOZdN1j04d6L5iOovN3s3c0vTPg9OpAAp@qizpeEny6MCyyEoXD1uRAb3EYFhL5yiPtViGuhVKolpn45gjE4jq15ssXgq1g9k@YOliZtEnHATlhm8SdIECWZ13iW8Jw9E7igJv0lu0qx0k3DA@len0huaI@MYEbPTvibrKya1ZSyavkXlwJU5jBUw8xjmhcW1n1A/XOf6criw8VPPrX0tKOGW303SzTaB0xtOwSMM1DK5tfJaw@9wvJXwsLTmZQJeONyusGLwgM8h7v5i7TeAKM6HsBzGwOGowX0AIcrYIEIC@TBUAqv4jxKLuV8dLLKJLd4ng9LjYnp5YYXUaR7FriRienIl7rqdnoBcCdcUAS/HEEgqB1vmbOHJDNQsV5i1WlCwopkjhzxHU6/KecUYfephkC6PFQ/2wdsumNKtnFLoVPjojdAum8NSC4B5E7FTzW7PRWOt0@ktSGVTwNYTUqBQw4UyfV1XPBnkQSSWdoqcXLioy2JBo48lpyNMKWc2iBEgnlgNaSoLxqYlgARRDi4vBksUB5JSZBK9mgFvETvI011VZrNRrQSjaotT4WsNaysCZBK2nQhX2NNsrk2BuGdtm5fPLKOXysjc6qypt5vWnEJ412WgFrKILlYTNaAt33j/3oUxUzWvSrDu1Bol1dE4/YOg0E/DufGNaHCmhW226CVBsjxN3C4qX8jIr5Ospm32LG3DCPCXgOcY3v4xboAUHY06DYA5M0RDMZItDoU0yzYvbQcKlZpNpkjKSKaukcPi@Q@z1YOmdxhyO/F6vF8kWRm9VO7KLQJ50s8tH9@3os6lFw5KvMf21pPOEIxiqJox4nXfIvgWMamVS84qgOgx5fdlYRV1sLaweQjgI4PeykcOBrymJfdEFAc3h1O/BBZREHNqGiLuuUjUMLVYs4lq@NQwtsizhq128HyVNZffno2jhYEMzC0bg2DqTAxTEtLp0Dggv@bzGL1BLjgWZRktqpdpOkYXB2El/ddF@0qKrQXpAwJOBnqa@sdghjbtP60BKDrjUeKHQsjofj80ragKOYdu4mXzC3sGR5Yb2wcEupfANrrby2uhVGfTgI6oOhWd8Ziz8loqcuSQQh3XugEFPvnUxARMLZrIv0oRkQwgntPzpC1ayjI7oZer63@529B0@Pnj14ikLUEu9ReH2D2jKkrtOsr2A8e75tOSKdIlehqgV2o0D7sJVH7RM023SKUORYLLV0bsFdFJmBwppcui@qj7wz9RiyKGj9Ak6ErJu7GZgeh9pgNvVi7W2xHEPaJ5julchrG9ASgmE6kZYQjJVcsIQtLv9qxBoqr0avIgbsqgO2yQwP7fa@QsMlq6BStbevou96ky7qktSM01KeRVTBR9mNnFOhyoXcoMcYrAn8RaOhHmqnuGK/1hn20OXtdECOb0/9Yee02@/UxyfjwiB0xT2NUxqE6OSygMpUO/vbey@OnmOcru1HZDmB/9qUt7/zdHv35T7mvICs25K8vbe3u3dECup7L5/vo8fQVFLRBhQsMZgkJICe7X724IkFw99FaSQbhIQgb8IfceVTVf74aEb/nZOZR5VVIY4oCA@ZqWBRSquqyD/1gqkO3ob@J/QBX0XLE3yUgbp0VGNySOPg9afkxb5OLywoasdkOo4IlDTgndRIlJMlGOY0PMYC5IsoBL6dtOnrfKOMeWjIF4ydVFk0kMFiBbHvGoS0OnCZvJiPeo5GJ448q@feCCDxtak0jQa1tdJFGb1KjklpKF241ICTo0HOUUvZJWUERSu9YAUxsq9d2wVt8A5QZFFCkxBbplABfkFsq0rFL58X7ABRkgW7KsePOleWDX0SRuLX3LDmiN2asp4v1I8EYn6JBY6hEf58bj9KEYHJ@xQZcxyg5bkZM/qrO8s3zI6ZHYfep2K77jpqjzyCBj@IHHb0Qj77YrqT5y5pwBFmpGc8mQfo5W1MOkwVMo2HURsGKprMFVsQhpEZLuj5If53Jq5de6hA4wDBlW3YYpFz2R0lGgmFEQOQmFfcKK7HbmzYLMEoDjPEfRuilQXxhQ2xkgXx1oa4nQXx1Y8ZxB84lYqevA21cucOazMn5jOj@P8xxWs1DXtfq0LHhQGfXVyfxoxkm3EIdMVFc1D7zAbkdsvuXtqyJOqv/i/gtnFJqRpVwg2/pNmXYP75vymu8w3dNUbp97mH1gaFzIk8ebEJM94XPhIS100SW9I0tr@6BFuxqGcxu@wfxBTxRQ7RfPXXCZhssvmJnndlxk@/cN2Iy7Ziq4Y0gr9cROC@D4IjLq/XF3kbZQNezF5ZN1h0D2IEDHLbBllJg2RV@e7SKps2vlZmlS0bpHmdKr/6W6lTzq8MiD82ELTXymBmgv6/xEIj1XwolAUaMiTa1DyPX31zwY@TbbCLZYE/j7FTkcPL2/3z30i3Oy6ZCf9vM4mTCtj0pac9c@D/53Vx3M7F8QNGUavljluJISqVXIivfha3g4c3vcwuWyQ///dXl27ml/7Xcen4mN/QBzdzDRpZegs06kHJTCp6YLDx/MEAmJSM1ljHqFlz1pLDs1gMxpIdaJlssThLZq/o7Hlm9m2TnUJ@wQyW5pLQvx4xRvc5wiCxRvFvsvJlhktnbrg211bmDtncLjPrYmAOY2N4HDHFsZiejZTAsZwQMhZRS25ZmL2LAnHB7UzhJ@xMOiejDgZoDYNRXSKA@EFj@zR47eNBNWmgm4v66zBPGvplWGtCQHKci@LrA1SogKaKUxHW/Wa5HQE7vd70dDrENzRX5Cp0jNRooMs4EgRH09NQcOKJ@3DqD6EHLnJqMYsIYt4YWkmnMLDS16o@VXVWtYtVNhqsN14nN3SURG3rTfxxRJW5i7IAunwiBhWq8O9bsJqFRwP1c0LErmhd6c8Tf@Q5FjxGcfWrVgL5Rai4XKpNlJEeEwtHFTVAnk1PExjOZcZJN8blnHqIFj9Os7qCI@ch3aiJhxFCjHWEH6oV8UFHrmUQiVgQTZJYVqqrZR4lQvQcyPM0CbFaXWliRWPMIhdF5BnaaJZ3BuS2iIxaCQdhM9A0C8ARxuhlXDea0DvIMO1yi//wJz/@78XyeaOh0yimjj/qgMxAEUlirPi5HzzX3xZ6lE/EVjGF@3/EuBl13@v5px2MUBNZqIG4cjDDBCLmcyA0dFoVDGG/CY4dyxeMrhAJq9F4sLWl9j/b2/0craH4EoGoIFUciWBdFSs87FQykS@KwQgilLAI81QqRiDdiEUo0ysEMz0m9zoDx9LAgtH6rf9Io0V3@QFquvO6TCHE7CI79cF7QtSttdGaidAUjPPwW/@BMQdj1p7NRhyMi0KY8HPsAfHrq0hnoV8MkV3f3//hf6HqxKIEeD68Vzm1q85j@in3QC5kiWZrrcPcXiWqoUHIRXzlEP3OnxGykIN0642wcMPeFQ2S7G7/8e8qwoGPDzB7VkmVwFO5EtFPGJF5PaCRy8VXuxLf7zG@vk@vADai7jzZxadwTtYnaDTkWMmNK4bv7/9QWgzwfoRvJpfUsZxobiFzMv7CnlkqK9ORN78W/twZ/iMbqZi55mHkgyoTz4//Nl6mdjfZdTLT9w1rdaaaltnhH/9NFvWRjjmsHvQAzmjtqcpcKzlt/s3fNvhnhRuzKwjmH/7kpz@L@zjL7dkstz8/jVfTbLEXs7y230htSd/DI6NYmeVOxV8nq0ms3JlrfeYh@Ku8cZ8lB3uWt@SB9M2in12x7POQ/EQjMQt@duWSz8P1expX5mJPdytnuc9yl7nGnrPQU/iXc5oJi/HP7cU4u2zmc9d8Pln8N0KODB8ajy5MS6MhHE6TWNv7qkV/0TMv/t1It8be/fCqLWZcXOCoAB1KTQnaQ6jZfXvln6djyl8wXxOntsTZgu6RVUtLagHRpDMMM6py3a@trhUcOhD3MmrZ@LBKCheNxshjo/vpuI9SB73fnZLkMaHnPwwekL0z/gbNJXDbIK6wtQ25JzigJh/SC064QD6IjnwOaVEDPUD3Qdygv/dNd2stTiF540YayzBglugGXaejKJQriIgkUWkdZgoVLKdmLoT/ZXYglq66LF3hYEkfyY9snHPl5v07PzM7khmlIIk9hbJyNc4/lWkgFSN6KyePHcLT5aN2E19GkEqm6iMg9@j@3/Zukaoun5e0wPIw/8F/MgedF6Iuax/6gyav5PEfg2PiwOSegNb@yT8JgVNejreM3Jr/s574kHeovMrxJLtGPTnV/Nm/KyJpZw8SZ7evFrIEY66MpXaeqZcvtvfU7sv95y/38ULGdoxoZPB8QY/Fbt6XSYBNXhIsyLJtEPNXWJy18pi8/KpfWSlT9//rT7H7jLbiFptFa5guLfdHiXItXe6SMaKpuPYIyfgslOdLC2gd1y29dd01GSEQoHdGEa7X0IMfAsYXE@zwWc42Jn82mbalbqmY8Vxj6r/OblmXMfmXCXjU4QS4LYXz5za/pYxvhjLoymqOr3du1mse44deaJefBPpNU1DiZjP7wvfs7Kw@wPBU04lf90J0TxSiY7jG@BiYhVFAl5roNhsIz@@BbIvOC6e9N/GvWq8zetsJUUHm0xmqRLv3Pp7z30LeHfH4@JRDcXzoPbFSdNtbnVd7VUBW7fbeVAdn/bZksGGwUTjhROR@JvrjNNS//PHAQAQR3rObrO7wTS8YErdb7A7hICvGVXMPNeRcf8r32GfDGH2JPBfvp4qYZocVKRQ@GlAO/ASuSlsX@7OD@WGi@MwUT2izhBwR81KkrBCM@azHQWEDZpw/iyvV1R7MxFm8MSHD1wdUCtGQiGauYRIW4ZgzY6X4DXyhwjSEnCfS0PKn51JpPd78BfPoasIAmhjDgHtO4@CLVwevDkehd7Z8WGkcV9HREUJ3xayRxpR89vBvHP3h2@E4CBNJIy@MWMGlqZN6J0INTCus@CJjldK4gWYZhRs/HjTUDnQpE7foB5Hji5kqaeOc0PN28aAYjzE37EAagyPtayUDScOHJ8vU3kZ0aCHCdNMlHYkvSxeq@PkE/Wlp2BqMOTqAGc3RjBADNSSXisQwVRfJVuFrGSfAsLMP3FRXdD5MxUEqy@rmhcy/3fyb7938AayL7NYTwfKmmFIam3mw4XqyXNgj5oZrzSu0oLHcGaLLv@L2iNzTaMXBcnu5oU1TuB7sggSdtSa/J44n@CV1JFooWNccZV81d3lZ8rrQQ2o0TeJXeMrXhCDleQPhCCIZxTwpNrOLgaTLGwc9i2UVO7MaOaNGzrgIQ89yGnkoxTCQp@224RCdtnXgPAJ8LdboJbFQhZ23GJ@KXREtN0yd8Z5DVKAtDGFCkc56h5m1H1iNtjatFAIkxAUEfW/QmQ6j9UJ6w2vVzJfZo3go9R7FX0IGvFcAgdEW3GalMscQmbxY4FW6T24v4ddBodiqNqst@l@T/1@s6kT9/9ZiYjMJ2UomNqup//1KEg9xZLPFolZzFTfkwi@W1HgenQSjlcKSMme2ojMb/RHyC@rrkN@Hw5E/HnsRhTlSx94IH7cx8Ksf4I0FOv/CuDrw@41H/kXWNXLFT7FHr8MjRHQkiOrjuSre2izCuJ@Og0mkvhz6Xf0bY5TfXdVf4TxEN1Kh5xEPFAITJM/cqO@7P5nvRLsjvJdooMfkKODf3WHQbZyCKO9NyJVjCGseIPygPpmOGuRuyhv18VmczBA6b6BpJ1AddK1/BGBH2C2njJQXeuiesvhqNhgUyXmLN@y/8JBxw9sjZSKp7PSJ7@iEJ0Xc1pbUM2DC1tndivZhYrx00Yh7qiSPcbUhx3MmjYGSFekLNd4xliVpZhRRKVre68n1X7FOD9BQqlgmtswp04kYRDG8VuWUAqwYkiiBfcQgfcwY41kR9whDhHpoWSKNqCglCdSO@FMqjROoIjmf/Sqwh9grbUXrOTCtzDO21tG9J96Vua2y2Sl8tJNqra1jbA7qCQ4oTpM8DbfWMIccVIYKI86xbxq7HxVXWgKAPCEUCBF47Al6ZOi@JiVSvKyDwwPpr67z8Hqiiy7RhhTjBe@vRt4xRUlRZ12fQ8H0/ZAAsGTj@Et/LENUTZBqd3oMrDatBYqs4ofh1LvzydoqNYjiGmnQftBLgK40ADO6lm1Q406i06Hpxb3oRA29t96Q/b9xsyn2Cy9KojNHtk@8br5bJtKBoUz0FEbBuVfltK3tx08e7G9vVVWtdQfB2UDVwDrW4HJ2hfLJgEPICIvw8q13764ykTthtbTZKJWl6Zv2sFfsBmsEsGdNUI4bOyWXisnNHCMGkamPe1XVxFs0sd1QVxuXGzZlOsGoBUU9uHrlLy0VkaSxriUkwcTmCGXK8aEBX7DxLADl7hUwArK7HaEQhqGEiHKL92/WamZNrdOvGmystdoG25kXH4Ec/kaV9qajxG5borXTUSXY5NBbHm9tN0u0L9SLbXXilj4KS23kzg3n9NaZls91iL/RAFvh8MDtBw/nev6cqdZagQEpH7QOy2VJKP3d/wex7yI2Cxg6Ufkc@esvXe0Sts6b@jZ70HRKfBsMxb6sR94sekSba@RGbVOgG/TndQpJ2n8EZ2/f@dKuY@yUz0m7uee6t8vnUOVkjHYoY9gMvX3AWG5j2iCRFoscr16N0C3uMspf33v65DOY8j30LxVGB18cLt9qVEslOOJJA8nFSB9qa/fpc7xJmJTrdKPweBKcyrhMOqaSOj7so@Uwtb5axK41cBXCznnsRdL78OF8v3P8rHMKEnMHhiB5gdOxtX4wzD3q8ttj5BaTk1ssnx@7BHUy8QZt5oQuQvetc1xuR/DnxK7iDlThrqwQ9ggKuehAIDXq/ghO68/2nz5xS/c7CrG6GauiVOka4gBCIYJxMIkE2gTpYDhdpKqI7TaJYOBfpVTcSPblfqOzUWpfXOS250nQ6bPHr1JMwH1nWhWKm7iLU9qexFQwH3suJvDR9p3t/WIVyqLsi4kU42hOmxY7I3Z1HUxuuFPQETh/gTCuu/rxx5SGRaah6640m2VUD7kAbOQDAtDywpq0LyYdt@@YgeyM/TpdnXszrouYk5X6SqMzCs@AHW207jbv3W5@Gkzw3aDvhb2PQ9hC3A6GlPWj@cdoyE/qZMfBcPDxwB/ig9XN1eW1Xf/hv/revRd3t5xe918AD1l8HQb4gD8Z2w2YdM5E@w/22EmPqYsaMQKcvU5j3HkTNFb7zd5ac631Sd/75I631ry91rvj3b7XvXfvXm@wutbt3/uk88mdXreBbqOpSP2UlAeLTP5Y7eB61eYxZmsrzXuDQat195P@nXuDeyvN27dXu2t3@s3V1cFaq3P79t3@ylr3Xvdyri1uTwE2WL3v4tmR3oE/ymfuCgt7u5Qu/yM';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxx                              # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU  ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $f &&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le./_e _=B[1;#]>847576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t}a, 8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);(!)=seq;instance Num();f=(^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65")#`=>ass#
#9'>+/' 25  pe+--[red[ ]print 221;]  pppppe^ee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*ss<s*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

Pure Red code: `red[]print 221`.

Code in polyglot is on the last line: `pe+--[red[ ]print 221;]`.

Everything until `red[]` is ignored (undocumented feature). `;` starts [line comment](https://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs.html#section-2.3)
in Red/System and Red languages.

*Note*: Red/System and Red have multiline comments `comment{...}` ([tio test](https://tio.run/##K0pN@f@fKyg1RSE6louroCgzr0RBySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVGJiys5Pzc3FShRzaUABCEZmcUKQJQI5uWW5pRk5mTmpYJ5UJVctVz//wMA)).
[This section](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/style-guide.html#_comments) of Red documentation is a style guide that advises not to use such comments (and use `;--` instead of `;` for line comments). 
Also Red has [preprocessor](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/preprocessor.html#__if), its directives work after first occurrence of `red[]`. 
Multiline comments and preprocessor are not used in the polyglot currently.

Additional `[]` are to skip `;` in boolfuck.

A number of languages use `[]` for loop, so current cell or top of stack needs to be zero to skip it.
`+` is for boolfuck, `--` for brainfuck. `e` for paintfuck. `p` skips `eep` (`++[`) in alphuck.

Wise stack at various points in the program (top of stack is 0 when `[` is encountered):

```
      line 215                   line 216
... : ~-<~-<~-<<<~-  !    ...   [...] ... ^
  0 0             57 0          0         57
    0             0  57         57
```

Xor `^` collapses two stack elements into one, so `^_^_` is before Wise code now.

First double space on the last line is for Pip. Space in `[ ]` is for Retina. Second double space is because of Incident – `ee` needs to be after `^`.

Answer (score 7):

## 224. [Nial](https://github.com/danlm/QNial7), 10637 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM3@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WHLKt7QznbbTl3RmykolJVESbYpkkpQtpdMfqmsWtVNd/dBTU9uo7t7pqurd3u0FBpjGYh56MD1YYPp10Jjf8NXTorFA/YPac06QFHWx0/lVNXYWGNoigxEnTkScOHHixO2wKVm93/42iBc70tVRV9VtZsuWzdqmci2bCbYxYk8lxcqmM4EAQlXN7qAva7ZVDASZyJiitZQ2vDNbv5I15ZNsgn@aMcPUu6bUZ3ZPsplstSRDtpg@sI2BzfTO/GgZxrb7@qUSx5h9ResCmC2bhinbFL7C2JmmSv1mW5oKyU4laJgQbrEtWf3c/2yzlt7vS1rbAsgcYy9105IRviVblo7RVxkbbsutKaR5AJVMRd@vHjybCiow9gyyKBmqPGRS07JNqWUruoY0SbGTg7OTo6kYoshen@7sTPum2Yu4rrGdQetqOijDzkxLUqVp/CusOrD1PXvaP8uqXVmTWDpRSKSnA3Nsw5RmoqwyU5baHUWVE1AhLM56smrIJkMf1tFNtgdZUvOpfKpRHcdMtDBufhw4jbbA1EzGnipPOgWE182erEEOU9OBohc4FZD2AtoKJSCZIxa2eroJfGSygSW32Y1utoG5NHUUiUF8NvzEmpIl51YQQcZDcKXpNxowka1D1TZHtsw0XYtTZARcYeJ@Y5qx0ln0rR7uTfvnWHp/2m8VGK111Zmty3SeHevGaNq3wF4q@/PYOZPiDWFTb0NtTIWJ7EgCL0pmkvCZ9GQraEHtQmNmlxZkrC0zS1MMQ7Z5IPCKbFIwxGaqol0hhgw7V2SzPZEmtfsjU28PWtgm7Z4MwdiOkU2sQAuQVZjhSI8EOliQGIuDAdoTvS/7UVpMk6HeLENuKR2lxflNHtqyZkFJrARToGw3iqqytqxChDH2VoxZOtb62KupSr1EKxFAfsVUWP9KZQprGQbjQVA4yNJOKs9kJCr7BOFqz2JDo88spQ/BdkvvdGSZfZKNHkQPtPUAg6tlTBXLe1uSAUaTXdLIBsgJJI2OFQB0cil0Y0pAcdNyaGArfaC3YocsJkuWgnIWoliy1iaqGp4E1pk00RLYtQJyAIo@MAm3JZvUEgkvtFpTBpSSV/vhG1OxbWpMrMqOZMlkp6YsRyal8USSkJiOKdhYkARV6tpaaPtwJwSVy2MkJAMq08ycvnoekFiizJYaJfiVBaEU2D7YYrdLF@jmwhcYwDDDUoSVv2VW8uJCht9QbCa75l0AsAaAKipL6oadlOIGZDBuQwaTEjrRFb9OJwzVlzBbm6oLH8txqDbUBsgk9jpGJWsNTBM7mDFRpSsotKprXaAnFNYcaEgPjeVSUAUtHfqHGJOvgWogkKmOQFwghU97ClSahVXia2@8mySCQkcJbOxQ1E3X0tUBwUFMy0ZeBqpAVMS412GvWUdSVIwC4YiK59qUrYFqY5yB1saah25QbieYmw1qxybw8TUkJwFS8gDW7/vaJWUKgKEidCoqBn33x3/e7nYBT7XVApHnsOtr1tZb1KFLlFnoJRkyLMhZlbIFcDFMnUeHBK4lVWmT3JC0kZMEZYJSvdEHapvpkKB5o0Ar7UnX0LKhcbVsmTM51wFirC9dcWmicM6FgvelJlQsJUBpU7Hj7Okm1FJLDgSJZ@L9gd3Js7ixzUJW8n14vRheX7yQIXORRGR5KZnsloDhEsvkBW@hhzjndXVCgFq2ZOlKO2CM7J6upVm8xYRWWTdkLRyawBGKhcxmKJJAKReOlJRyK9FRtHY4tAa8WIGEQ5FSq9yqKcV6aSq6P0lAc4NosLnK4VZECIDIoUZxneyDkE9An/E67rh8YbrVQJJjcMLnjYSZ9rvmHkHSgZAvdWQQkEMJS5VlI5xKiBEUEwg3t9wYMK@kUzicAheVejQUDEX9RScMUNKJgmJjPVV0FFuq0cO@DIiiWQb0BCbybgs6cJSMlmKDIhpjTeJr6kVAspBMvJFDpow9vcdH1CR5k8P4cRSUDoZxE5psyXLb15BBCEBbtq0ZaazqN5Ag5Qm7GRAdGiYqdaFqIDIvSJUXhKdEPpNF4voHYGvKLB9vKtAIsLmBTHd43lc2AM@kOQxg443EJ3v60giwtHi3Om4wTOlAW@qDeAAlqSWjzAHhI/MOBRMZUPuzQPVGJTwVT2ezk21sponZZrIafwdC@lPywZaEhfc3JhQ0rCPfMFXSugOpK3MFjUmtlmzYjqCCklg2iKLp/oY8407nmbB6gaWn02lTJ@KqFuM0UMjz2nO6Qgmli6P/x0HLkZnkjGBAoTRBLKmj6dQB4HoqceEDgkxk4INwTxZcDQCYTB7KrYENUg0Y@KantHrAs5g7jctF3glNJw9e/tRBssc7XtKYGbHyJB1IJD0vzMa9KOJYo7N4oHNFVJUJD6p8v8fDmCWrPwex7mUROgKfbyIpJYD3voCzr2v6HKRASA8tgkyG8HoATewEFUrouFy1ixqrp2V6VQR1huODNvJfz7YNqwj9hGL3Bs0EcEry1Bzt2YcaMkvSNkeKrXN3U9WbIJYtaJ9JN4Vka9BUhlMFIj@vDi@twDUoYB2LlaHn/jgArguHOhYITPLfRGBfkECCm1DwuwCABJQAQoU7FoniHRAqJyOtFRYS1JQS0OiEGBOw4QowChIwlkeXTb2PUoidk2KAmh6MBhUNhxCOzCeRL83t6jzZT3pdKJS41BUtfBtaXFwMFUMVkOyLi@vgWkPXOrqi4FonV5xcCJdAF8WIkQtDaxQD/eqhu5qLeRipY7UNsVf6pBhhqVYsZuoxqSY6zzQ@IyDqQLIBdBwfgCcUKZfRGYkIlRsoaKLZmSz9Jkrnk5apGA4RnkvXEn93qJAhMih9A0eXplzCTvZhmvTLJvSCoLS2emEzdFFLXdQvbi/a0Yu7UAxjR0pSuQmFgvTC/UTX1AfQXUZqK8W4WI9EahnoJJvlUCq0HA7n4yokJEUi3@QjUYlTOxySQWqHLy5CQFSHPrVWzyR8w1g6EvFIBfnAjhl0wnAocZuH9JuReiQagriRUAyGGOVQCCjTQiJYVGjkzAkCHR6/4ITZjEYDxIa6eYW/GbEPfgkYYPHoO8C/myeTo@H@FUhX1rJUVEXiJtdG4DW5zD3b9PA0riLbI41Vg@4WSgC9bdsbGeEgXRuQ/kzKre5PiIaDCEF@2PegXFUmYBBxRxnCAAHa/chVhLD/Rl1oEwacuionzkk1ERg0HBwNy4m52tAR71YSLWvMA6D3gNNQpRY07El0FwK7AITA58nk/JBIaQbxtKpEo5ovlRE6lpakIf3aCmntA8XqIXlBs8KhhNkBqqLKDrqBTFTbYy3o87tAaXmo2FyHBz46wSi7khWOoNZY5VoXKnuoMWCm3DkA6s71Fox3ZNAcMJQPHtm2dq2YuoZETmwDamD4EtbBFPJ55AU2qlb30lv303cecqDYjLfoo60f6zRxW1aLJTVd1bs6WwYAZM1EgjP2noYzKKDz2TC8ZJbyiQhU7eraaIoHZezuLdQRxVzG074lhEwSfOISZA2bX@gxwD1lPtl7tw09hJhNpSD/7luKLq@QPizTZUTPFhsDODO5KvIN1uQ72eiNJuaZkD/4KBL4SZd5w@Tjegk6VMiV08I/UVR/I@c@0M7doLbrmlf2bdKQcCrDP8qYKD0og9BOneLwZgMlDE55o69LigmkMxU@rl8UXBfJCbnlDZzinb5uS8nXiZ7F8BZAfSGuMMFKhhZDyXgc7wIFsXSFJdvydRKllIMZpPJpbyAH5FZPZ8IF6C5@IAFEaA@U8DgUQjZJzfOiOXPWAVsfgL7YllWlr9h7NJGmaqgUjTt8NxSnCccIjhTZDjgjmbHgxsmusRTXuhz@GIQiYYWxQ4KX3JTbyWUeuj3EjtAKyPRkB4db242j6uluWUgOLDOpKk1oOW250QeFV5UtgU1fmAAk5cT/dKUe67pd5mxypbIvXkGM40bf32rs720cV4/f8kwQGkvpD1QJs1JcmgLA6CcU7LZm3/xjx9T73kjAcqppKYMVI08sQeCw2AldwdCBswDh88@hfx8XFRKtQLfVYnGdv3qeDuAqAuJCA/Wd3WgUIWnhwfN0IPOEEhcfEmbT9Sygp7fsMDEhP0Y3L/z@SA7mWzF1h8gtbWAZvpLdiiL5X9udDmoLnneavK/i2MTUsXeGvPmyxeSCgUOWmaC5wB6@FcLHlzvm4psJmgvs4ctyfLhMMh/dVMg8UA9ZjpDhsspcXFMBcwA9TKuEyb8UMw7LU9h96zBOWnOD743k4S4QblyrGaOilRvHywVMc@7o83UUq4Fzs2MeSYsToRjEV19YvA2DojUEQX75jOsy4AXao2W0E/bQHqPI@FHEQdfhqzJeOGcEUW1IDWiV49y6Pr4gFldBvIm5ceSsF1mfiqorY28PnNdrWm2ACBj4mrTr4w/yIvEqdJd//I0izWvQ1I2Rry3fpjnx@4ojTnytK8PJTXIItTJzIpBT23CXgCbCeLPkyz6NSz5J2HBWffxVluH0vsGlHhoFkIA8BVVgXwcFbl@xaJHWLzED3kDjIiC4o6WJYYEwDkmPZy1Z/Hr@dKvgR0SyHMTtlY6D9LGrkUqIWcTioehfqbMxO6Dr0m0CdCZTsyG8D@k3O3SbA1B0ZvKgM8WlKaTKc1yNwMlGHUYe8g2B0ZyE032Cgiwlj@mBsxPz8jM5zzKRmabcGYBSnoRBI7q/ABYv5Amy02wq94ECXTDr7nNuIY8HMDBKJ1YSojsKw3lNGInxSZLTvUMChHbdm5mcYxNVYQ9MG2I5z//8gzZUyWyF9aQRDU08RwMoSdzSubf@nKj4Qrf5dU0wlwNVkYgw5PoSypaE6yGS6jnmo0Zdh8XjPcns4wjAqW5gV7xBM3qA83jOTVkdtGX3OT@RIiMiT04CMk3ps9YcaIKdmq/kidGYT9WlNpGBj8wUmSKZWNm8GuQhH6P4VGAQUvclNGdakY3X8ezewB7wOy7dfakaFQN/9xFhAjaVlZqinNQtqanID1S7KV0N2nrcuOpSoTFruTmw4/I3cRYs3lGlK@5soHM@AXgRTaXblU33eR/YTQ8GGzRKSt7Q4wHOcFUuRkq09BBOU@X3@0DcPTWe4346KSrdHlHRHkMRi7SgkSBpcX0@7iOTMkVYVWqOcLTY@3rOwgRJlwU5U25Fo6kMdr7eYsx4J4Bh3B8fe2yKXyjMj813BnCSzBvLJPmOgDifKaMyO3sEvtDIoetS@pIaT7d9znuluDsLO3bNAaWpg3hLlSxgJtupDvkaqo9uDzE49kYtZKux6wH2HmfHXZO7b3nHaaVOS27pqmJhc1bvk5rTM@LjNHFvBt3GUfFtlrBtUo@tXtxzzZcEesvGtZV7GO0Rko0va@DCkY9zEvp9RGvpN/i7V7no6dcyv8/v3D7NzdUjZFRcJZZQWnMFaLv1JU7F9Xm6zafj1dx82S11rr@zijA5RHgsL1uKqlswVsf7Q6QArduy@H0@F/uppkhanCa7/e750ZxMGSzhTO7dU5eS2tXVXL6blOB2b4UPzA5Kfuf5WInnSSxR/LLEcvUgXROd572i/ippXn2JE2hG3MSVM5/zgX52nthyVlzuLyCMH3A5fH7hdlJ5iplI8omT@yrAbPVupJH7/B69yX3UdXsTY0R6Nah5GKGQB4dtcl37@6S28nBq7ceJpBm0q18qhK9yr1QZOi@6z1QpS6fEr4whplKPF1AddSAP5Lny6bB5KeM@yQdGG4/PVMopxpIzxZgE4uEEowf1yRk1PirX2G/j24MCRlIVaORf1G7myjsDdHEDB9pH4DhCx2zErjYwJip3YrSmHT9MuZ7htmy9PZFJDPlaiZT/sg41oa5bMv3uU@23@zqMjfU@qA3aI@rfQUqzIfw@gZh8xorGxKTJ3OS95XXQZUH1gBpVrqw4zqY/Tuik7xvQE3ChkNQUTbZHeL@P0vOEaFPX1a@pGZClbYX2Q6tx3Or6pRqaUXOcnRZsPHVh4TRIs3PfpAXvZ5zBJVAPx832AyNl/xTVA6PBmen2B3or3@T7l8aX0FPTrJBltlz3fQxJkx9iIp9YfZAduRaqN2VV4o9hbuUhfIVE5kF8ntbhqLe0lIPLP3zBZ7wWF5wSPcYIiKW0YWzSk/syvT6g1Evty4HlPu4FGur4mxOcSNICxT3xDAXauob3icUlnzZk6xqMpmzJ7Mo4HFFxPdXxvU@@uusec4m715e6Mj8u8ZDoGM9K4BY8PogbO@fPTxT5rpgWROObBh5mBWg4V/LIcp9zEb4ctaA@B/0vz6pNtfEWzn5@sVEnknOXe76g7mk9vaf15J5JjcN7u695AEfa/KDLQ4WA/Pck6wr3HJI8Go/mepafuqquqo@hLspDLh11ff7E7DaeF2hD1K/CO5KaEOA8vjhjB102EYn67vvaTk8eQM9k6bZuyHF6uw9Uxckefr9Parpz8o@ZMmqquoQbWB9Q04EG7vMxGFu6@cUZjq6k24ZBj4ahDiy60dxtnM5xzKurHcrpY6pdsfmuFM6ccldvtnrKl7LUlCVbU66S7mwNf31wBOqIXSq5wuJb6J1QFaCVOUpgdZf94Sf42LuvznyLOHNLvzkwzdGXRcDkjgBvUpWvBaDjvvSd5dk5wdS547Yrd3vRAwsSzmruvdxEqjKqxXE5BfqHeO9cz8QOM0dO0bLiPerNVLkpM76VtK@ZpHS2A9B0neLb8AD@86Yp7hN5u44kg/FfeHfQtSJfZtxeG7QnvM1FWO3iGS@@ZmSp@o1vShk6HElzHnP7X2/d8aHFjuyDqx2JpLPaGZcH985jqYph8TuLd9Jzscwu389CjeaPaZ3qacsdviCBri/pcH3dxG32oCzEW6ZstXBuG@Us14y4yNH0LsjbuMrGwC7s3CLM7hiYp4VM9mXxNwdyV8Jtd/sK7sBTrdnuDTBPbx54DOJXA8lSXg10W56Lc3oTwWNQvpS6Smt3ohZchC51nT1a/DHRCNBrtiJueopFu51dx/yGw9mM1uNnA6enz71Tdw9Pefg0IGfTKYvvMXdzqufACXwMl@amNalfOkvx9wo6xaapUec5t5zzN1w8NF9wM@gbA8t5zE@9j2cX/HPE/Svyt24UkILxjyB0WU9S7fnzyL5pUtCcnJ5w7LxPn36nqHqXvcunGChaIOBQvb6HsTagXz6SbGgB2hxmpfQfuUKJsxBxkxfuIzCCnGFxRVPsh2dcbFuCEY/7xAJxpQrP5iT38Z54@rUY4qfzqbL/oMSHLn3UUmEM8yWoo7dfgJA3v9y1fGGBBbpKXRvYcTzP@FAXkXuwiyiyYT7n4wEWfrX98iziskK31@J7Hb@giVkyjN0Gljoau@5d1p/DYQoe775fyM7GcAcBW3JHGqj2Ma7dPSZe1TBUnMMAmb6lzxusHI2gi/mqEQ/0EoP@ltzCNb9H5eFAfwnqGfRbBkjV/rGMi/RTguT@yBh1X29JKtCs/ajkTgj9vLKeSoa8AXWufmV5OcYtyZbmYZVxnq/zpZF6Edd9mrJ5yY@6Pwg5m4NdeUhDi/tZhus2cbvV4mo0zp1NtBTfcBryYuhfmJQEXQ5k/1eP5xO4r3aiN4u3HtUkDq/5Ng65fUJ7OKx5pD6Wm7r6ZUGiKXz5XjIV2UruK9pgSH4sDsrYdNO@cHYI0ylp7zydFXO2gYOfYjqHea2Ee2I@SFvm6XSde9qKBfHM3wD1cls3E4zgwmEpGo1EAjwSrmJ2NQBzoejMMp5n5MehLQbizyZYpcNqNbZ0OyymiuIdKzOhKLB6nWPFi07XbQ8NOnB8zKPXlqR6eSkUj4eWQhdakaVCHrisQg8/F1yagO0o9OD5HZOAaRI/GIFut8Qlfl7T6tFZaBjNtmFUfKbRtDSOsPmpQ36k9RS3Sf39X7edI@JdGQrbV0DLBoKghQS9L/f0m3WerpM6yC4Jj5gjDlDIVH7gMb5ZZaApwPCZnwzXb9jZzmneOW/qmGOAlyM@vPJywSsXp2rxtIjNK4/nxtv57yTsxXILBf3SoK@xG6Vt96wEtGQ6CDIwxzurwYVgmm3i/Ew7xvZYW8bdKXS@h6YkVV2/ooN6mJO//2t@ypZO@TinL9zk6XS9L0U8zCPS0dZWSx9Arl0kn2RTd0DCSGRQzwY42c@wxyb/CJ59oeO/wJFx9/ArJcNPwG5WT1h8m4XQ0gSeqSspnfBS9fjZ61qqXv6W9ZPyf/5BMnLrEE74Jl7IWUKMuSClO2Qsf3AWgsehISYsDQWeoHcESnH6mxteH0AiiTMZnoJyeUzXDafVkAEDOq/vcaNjXyeMbqpn9xRsn2wfEMPKN3QKlg4IaNjboFEBzYIGBq8RQs1bXXkpPOBz0vETm2UhQTxJLIGLW0ugQ0F4ohOjLA3ZZ9ZDJgO5JmZT8MYJqeIh4n55w92vmPHvKk1uyc0B7aS6TifSmTIVZ6lRXquQC0Smjof5a@8vhulU/GK4ul1PWi5RLy6G36TSb4DqugmxniSx5W0fbN0uJSqpz58tacQE4S5U4pteQUws3R7tHW2fnFZPz06gFu5c8bOjm31pLGuQi@joSU9XyUwC0AUF5lfIH@8NwMNhtiSxNbQLFIkE/KcbCNShtRAXlrjTJ5omYn8h@rz4luwLnwVwZFpHYS5H7UHXgXUIzIZUw8IPDDT2wJy4zoF14jIFZTw2II8wuLV4jiwlUgmsDMSKA7EeSSp2f2HXud9jKPZFLA@TbX0uCFLMS6/mhfMiziXB3e@l3AZ0lL97uTmWh8tNMA@UG0A9XzfOTnVv/@x4ezIa8Bg9SeqWC1nnWA8XztjS@OK0e0KfTl46EXE@vywwgSLwV6czI6NPTdm@kaFYjnBs9Xlk4lDKvxAYMyZQpoyWs@olTotwmHKAOkgJizV16qijDH1ZdPtoH7pbXkRPCOwIHmo34wnBwRwkc0UJvNxiIFaHXG7TOyIh7sjrkOVXf2Jui8OiYR89sHibu6er8nodi8G/r1dyXek6GzKnOxPrLM7S8FNlrQsFdmEjJd5HsSVOCGGJ513w8oumciBP7UuJJttoo6tzsAp6aVUy0C6HA32g23KRfRzodHrUFSaefnGDUzkStwpFVduSsDR0KlWz0caG228Rvr2dkzJqZ1w1I/nu57mBhh0VAPlsNME40UQrWx2S9dzaCye57hgWcbtKUKF63GYAKMaelmCxa8VSmirnrw7qOCpISiyNU3C0m0bnhllVtUAnaUP3za2MkXKSoMMX/ARGXGNCEHgy4amMMSYEENYqzxqagK70BgYtrQ888hLBEWbLhzO0thiPA@W6iuba@Sqi4S@aXS8y2xzgpqZKaCaKm4UiueI9u6/6AOeY3LmQk9/98Z9zMzsXNrh/7LiHqQ14@4nz1gH3H7khoghv/9J7S8PbT/nb@yRW2axtESd5Z27h3iMtwJdPhZkyoUxwjZ1RWbzaxpp@vXfELFrpwrrsS0NfNaGEQZ6DsRHwXx@Y4prqGMF5CuMqHOMJ114DiwBfAX@geoMaDaUnm/UwWpgoJpOYcZyOS9B5B3nIl7nI4MTHARpaAiUsmcvmVsQkZDJ@7SKkU99d3HHPEUYiRZCJgWvFKH9otvCAFROslqTK5VyJ80ZySXqfET54GV0C2AAfKNQYxMEzWV4MCKs40cJLUlSMYFTsyEJiCGVaW@esBtpgmBwAEkFvzT3cCuqm7pAK@FiThzZpTCN3ANREO3s4PS9zc1suojgg4rjRHNB0cxzvocczR74GmvBXg3COYCcIVhTmMWvtPbuwL7S6YxaKAeP9cg7rauD@wzm2ojhn4Tn4WSNF4WkTQ1ga9vRE03GcvgO5ZeF0Mp1JirmIj0MFBxXkF5v6Z0AJjRuERUtWLnXDqm5u7z0/PDqZMbZDkKFpsBALVdaiF/FErFb3HCEv35NE3dhJnrzc2HFJ6c/VeDsSQoz3JE1nc15q0zm9J/VzfnhhNm0KmElITD0WMW0AiO/Qlr1Z7OPQpA9wk@@dnkk1HLm9q9XXKhdacCb5z/MMkAUTy8hc4LqwyPxYaDqbmMU990jGKdo7tRLuUby0MDav55005O9j7/vN5XjWU8c2c9zDHwE6cz4@l56451gIlD2R5EmRwRieMTe/IGvcrIqY1XGCrcDMljJ/bphTlllDr86xSY9Ih3wOyTXTaXFIi4Qzn2Uiw1UezTy4UxcjNv2xFRvHfEsPcqcqzcCNY2nAPXTqWRlIWIaq2OFIQHMgpo@fzkJaDxqD8cCkcm3IvPOSFuqMwwQtU4TJ1tpNPcBt6TDX5E2UrOYcDYBuR7rBxrNoW7LrOgadim0N@LS1zJ4P@gDXocexjL2FDFpWHCIDPUNuVmpoJ8ahRKLfzoaHkURPHraVLvQ44UgMRNM3oji2tyOhwRjQq5rzSoDTUkZPgjJg1WTW0FzNMLJWoNdxAfkcJLuZ763VA4AMozYjRT5zETrTXNNoWPFFFop5lGlGYqEE4yMpx@oZshSfiEqwzR5uIqapj05HIZXNb8WCd@YdxewnsFTQzXAWeoZHCPxc81Wmj3yUkWpSQtHa8jCMViaKdaQT@Iduzq9DEWGGxcn@kmNtpz1tiMmVhZLtCKWxEaMpeVcoeHJuUjQUCmipAk/ewqAEUjyxzX1wgooQ7vQlg4UHZMnKYglGr@GLsBazbDPC4hXsrm@YxqJRmtOABwXAmAVBO@RSyGRIGA0/hpNlqCT0tbQ2Pj4pBquJiUQd3JRIhC3hfOYmaFM4ExgJwBgVohQJLegX8FfEHHHrvQnHiu8SJRsgYzIANTeY5BSuSIF8AVpQqVnlic8Ix1jAcKoWCkWnNialfYEBX6zNEYiAdo4Ud8cIQF/n6CRQDWU0QG2aclsBefn0haxpMhAIeKaPxoqlATCZGYm5drRjY4OWlEKQZ3HXOYsJGZ00dLkdulVxoWcpWaKpsdIdqDUfLlCv6TiazSj53ycTydJteEktj5Kga0Yq4aVeWYxmlqPRJW05vKShtvXkCc6o3S2BMtdIwAB1CEDxJTVSAn4G5a@8pJWWpLXwUrucXqYY8ApD5FuI8K2VTNwuSXfJpSegLMXAx@RCJ7xkkQ2qVCIh3kH@sIUsJWPAM7doTImsY2PyS0o0inlILDUwA98mL06i1G1enCRp8q7kjAWS3b7T3KZUMa8mZqx6cwI63kWvw8pih@Xsq224wGMzl5l5YfeofzzhF3j6gNFWKtnyD76EyZDHCxZHTqPMdYRMmBsBAwIOw0BEfI1JkQgIk9/@NijmGBPWc5mwHl3PpkrRUFaEYTqMr4NPQQ9PLgumcHuxFb9mcied@xivSZ3Ex/rR1dHRm8hFmBVYKLh5KIgrwns0YP64a5Wl77nY97@CweVkIJhcFp@sJpMfPnyAEQdctUqiAuKDX5FaPFSvhVcZq6yuLsdy@eXY01DDl61IOJ2OnDBFSbILxbDabfjpPTJlHw7ya32d0oLhP/wz7uek7zjcFwRxfINfCXctZYPsYlWSlqMr6adaKZFOpf/@bxfvYrdHjbW//4N@Ul7ExyE@fnz3Et0nYvabxcVvNjZWVmJASO4@enf0tlqtrmzFske17PpKPLW49p/@4@JiOr2WTi7WLUush2pXb4R0akVI/P1fho6OXjUsCwhRwCvDRHDiPQ8/kWWz7Ip9guuqw/Cf3J/aPreE7mbnExr@gvFKmYRNKJTNhE7eh@ZX2yITK@ur/@Vnhx@DdrCSTp6b8LSDH4O5fJA7wQFvGfftOlgJriFY7i44SpbLZXCu/pd/C/ErzwEPhozW4FbJurhyo2AlXqYon4OVHDjEdBrS/b9/8INAsDIMfgqKohgc0V8D3XDln4hPGDqSwmpe0PWn@F0CvIa@a1yKpCimL9z69FU3Vq3n3QPcUK9M9/l59e5xFXO4gRyPhavAbRuvf/h3//Dzf/gZ/f2cfv8BLbDnFp9@2GJMhh4Yr2Lx6Uw97E@9HyficCW81hHE17hTsmC@HGvwXHksHPQ5pujg3ZlDEu/9K@ECQdfiMMqhOnupjeviIijmVw6fTlTQ8AuWoILexZxkPJJ6ibNpP7cyvBfmygL2NXCB4LfsJb80Df7h576iD3q8RD@N3zQO4cJ43twH2WEdrkX4o3@4vFe8L5KP400gs9fi7yB9A8FasFav72r41/yIf/uf8O@jjX@nLfw7/oh/p5/w79jGvyML/1428c9fM4Hg2tpaMBo9BpXRYdrHXGfwSyQazpvHvMFA8Pd6sQA0h3o0fndXS7wfRksl5x/0qJL3hhd3QY7qd/H42vtKNFqjnNUqThbX4iuHuUP2tF7huaZ7ovF@DbBH12pra2V9k36JRgWveP19pbY2iYPQ1CtPn0axyT4FFJV6rRYI3mKtlPG2zGr9YadO5nPK8ZqYy9bjyIOXww60KAtB0oKQXEbHZ5T80JUXAkHUggtcGS6Qx4df/@AP8Xfx6x/8pEBfLMGQAPJ4OLoeXU@pqeuUeCVevdQPx/@Hh0MIUIapS91M9VI9sQ1ilaXks9QoNRqm@vqh2AanDH@pPjiVVGeY6qa0lCaKo@EEqvv/@4e6/fJQB2w6xLSHKRsRpzrw7B4evgR8HUj7Ev6UVCo1hEwOU9fwn1JRyJPVQ3q@b0QuAjUmfJBBhUiIoUQqlMiFQko9mzM@CrFQ46IWqpeCSeviIsmVK5ZeKZG1y7u7RmP7YKvRSCK7LUWfRuNP4SpXomvOYz1YKa1fFONYy259B5Nr6xeVTBzduShUYBr9ol95jTHCs7J4EYDR4vk5/s5vrm@4ixzoujinq8GDz8@T3Ovm3Llu4Epe34NgwsFAT/0n@m8f/tf1//KMhWv1CHD67R0MfemK4F8kcnt3e@fcK5Fw2HkJr8EfesA7xrm9q6CTgG7BVQtH6pG7O@4H93BkjSOsYCJrFYo8BoTWHOSpXoRKjMHAKuysyV1cDFOpSKkJPt7svPSZlnciJdr4stTEJTkYTIjLEQLJrpRKK457NV8q5R23mMuVSsseVApeHCcAyZbUKiGjl4JGBPPA2T@cwjkZMikcCrflDn5bYt0wYGAoFlKfP3tejUZbMRsN9M98/nwBLSmE@17KhSz4pPKfP0PzC0Vg0HigOyuuBRgCisn0GH1PsiTbNsOfFCN2EcLtedZFKILh6VQKgTE@y66t5VYqldwKuHP5SKQkLPFNM@FutCBG7paSAi8GDOdCQSdIzK9GyPcuhOEsuMbWK8DiFl7s9i5I1GYr2Ui4OZIjnodYKHAftpIL56MF56@8GGHJyjJz/mq1THRleXX5ab0@1k1QSpRupbJ4V76VijjFcFdqOfZ8cf@09ORJpgBkyadKF4FGY6t6Wm3gh1Fw@RplLnqSvAng0qRhhmo0H5Qt1GtYkPpFKFQsPeX1ms@yYKjkwMVDILlYvkDlDcKgU@ngwYkhYEW8gWBRXE5nFpPZ4Te57RQMlpbxqtVq@XQ@ugxybblQqNfr5LvGY7DloMHE1UxwOWDQbqPVFGvjgq2Jk2iL4Al1x5q4tm7JquraSb7RTbV9o7TlxUDwaL@6uX0aS69B15TeqW7G0idnG0ERX7PjdwrO4PvxdnXr8AwiHO1vV0@2n@293j47An@0qgpX/0iSB3JDvhkMbvC9IdO1qVjS5aVkGA0DrmGHizm8vvvlj7775f/w3a9@@t2vfvTdr37@m1/8/Efw@2v4/ZQ/f/pvClm8/@YX//KvvvuLX4Hnf4Dfv4ff3/7mF3/6A/6j97@D3//l8/s75@eD478A4PrJb37xs7/8zS/@6M/g96@d35/N/v74b@f/fv7D@38Y72d/9TDMT/8t/P4PjsuF/elfcD98zsD/BYf7oz/77k/@T/7/n5w/dP7quz/5O7w5Lz/66Xc//Nl3P/yD73744@9@@M/T3/3p/yam/Le/Aub5x7/5Jf7/7G/@8d//Ev//9//lH//mf/rHn/yv5Phz7vh//vW/4fdf/8GPfv3Df/XrP/jFPfcfPXj/xSP8f/FP4PP4fD4Gz2PK9bU@v/he@fldqDFOBXiATCmzNKhSGyOZlVgAxE6K36CN/PwPv/vTfwGs9ycACW//I7zBP3@BoB97L15IlEar8ejY88eMfU6Cjpd6@tkDBZT/M/qCN/s8iY18U67vb37xr/4SvSdg/4UfQ0qchV1CYC@1H2Pb8TLmh/0xtr7vfvmD7/7yn3/3yz//7pc/QYkaXynEqrG4@IVJLwDMPgIOAXOPgQNAcQ3X/xfZYiANjsU1nKQJiNEPH4Csi@CCIcVyIJuBt2C9TqOSi1qycpG8qPCrDu@JZAV9EsmLJIYnkjAiabBvYDSHv6dPl9k38Th/jv0CYoVQQx6j0BWJMPRb5nMuURzIw28YWCnAG87CRKEHjfKgKARtRFm5XI4GhmUII1B4xThDVsnjnACOIsuAFyPxOLFGHpRyNtwgLBCzHD1mjeXykEeMokeFMDDMEHodC2JaiObLW5BgebjFEBcijwY@wPNDuZIvDyuI7lvKAuCIbkCSAFXG3A0r38J7mXACfGC49S1kJV@ORit58ClTUSm1WIPSFLNUOCp7lFG50R/G@vBYf8rYN4KYF/gwF2qGOdB4j46h12m2Zx3CL6LLTnHo33XSbxnjQ7UPiT7cj4evozfFdwAAbzyOW8/gB9UIAE8heMhRRSlZeEQ5BqBc1JmL8TxIf4kGolS/UXqB9CEPj7vWKr4XRIfFWVpaAtdaRcgIhzAUYuZV0bIlE1dmSMUrMiFXENAbd/LIS0c0WFreWoa7CP/bi7Qbl5NjObAUwtFyiLlpxKMZfUUPUu7dolFZlinnUYILBMf@XD2n5TXQq1dYJBCmbyJEsPQt2TDg@dLqbuhDUKFjghATc3wCPeKMyd/qxWL5W3FlNQBPeh/g5xicDwNANeAn@hLYWJGgldv4GjVccIImlgtUKs4SIRMDlZPtU4hwesjEdCrBQO@@XVlNr2RXsulMLpddTYsrucJKLpvPgNDLpbLptFhYWSnkC6t3lKWnIDhixeVmdq3yz2au/@6fzbvm@@IVqLxhwwSL3wUqw3g8maYcl8XsamlUhnyQV6BCcxV8hDG6jePO0MAF7US7xU1PkK3AbRzZdAEuFlgIsAXwggvQ4uIIc1bs9w5LztIlfuiGL18KYhYYIRK4AEbg2ALGvCuAlfcEJM4TkTuzubEzhc5TPF15AOlAVWhsH7eK2jo71fmWxA25FVhzzgVWAgFa76kBYesB/JpErR5YS3qh8zFt9vg3IDdNHdT07w@zIWlXPGhL4SfCvKBdCY2zWX3F7t0DcWb08fiPbP6TYdjuNyGDOK/LATbgZqq6Pg9glZ0d3VPKl95pbVw4pePaAH6892z31Pc83a5u7gZybOPwYGvqkXWAsmx/e@fUe13loW7UrIfi7fb@/vSr88Ch1iLLrsZiICPhhs8YXfRMLL13QcTE/X1xFxgZ@qjkGlvqMBxQZ6Hpw8ivXJGGHRgxyolkQ2aN8kYtWK/kV7KruVRhlT09GPQHSAPWHeT3DlHaCZlVoSisC2JBXGdnxcWSeWvflfADiS3JlmIsD7IIN9MVRH4oRLECuzCK6@PnIvArK3YAj5q1cUMFjs6b@NG3gcHu9YQHeqHTVLo9kIE3ugsQaEoSg9/XXhBf9l/2wx42T4P8ZkLUOeC4fKh0QONM0KxeupDP5guZdD6WLwBpxVw2GxPTMXE1v1pIxcSUmBdz@WxBjOVXCpkVkJYQmi2sBoIgVZROMgmdgSgI9FS0FhpnXkMr13qiVwkE@aQI9MBhCbr6CAtKwYbnO8gzIZO/SEFkAT@6Ydm0Z3hZKQv4QeEUfq4XUEusxYI7O5upnR1B2MAXnMXcTAlCG1@y@VRqdUMQZArZBNGeFgSdx4EgALP5Syq1sSkIA44Az58LQg9ftnOo1gqCgi@b1Z0dTOcSX9IYH8CueAh/Ud2XVQDT8CWTIb1YED566ACuyhNaoZxu4wumiSE7PGQTwgThmZufVAowHHM4jmHXLWu1Kgh7/KVaxZDnVPAsz@oLfKnSJQgmvAA3CkIXHF1TljVBaIITeVIQWuBqjSTwQ5PYeFRZsyVBGHECIYkEYUjQUutKAIXL8cdkdnd3pZ7dlrv8Gpn82YKsQYgyHGzvNJ89a3a7TXNU3X52jCHPn@9Kl6OB2ew2nWjNBlw6xIGQq/5o@oI87jUakjo35AWEaFMhjVFDxrw1pI@QJ@fqYiL9xnMIeQ4hwzkXxwZXH0CbeG304bkhNSnEvSiEnsNmUygho9ojQ8ZpJGw8tPUq1pdapl7C92F5MRQOxUa1dL1EvqwfjtymSncY2AnTJ4BQUEZuR7VhOVUHHVws4WxWeLGPQisrFBel9fAQ3TkQZGJ6RYgUF5eH4YtYI7IupEELLuK3lPROiIXi4vogL@RA4i3DE6QeCr9hOBXC8WQoFYvUVuvrwioiFdbX40JNxFeAkeIrmAKKytWCECndASls6KqaA1tuNMLhG1m6ikQwt6hTULZxgjxyy7eajaisSqkTHsaGZZ4dNoqUsDCmbA@gq0rN4GzjEe1By9ZNjrkLhBmup4pUeshMHvORTEbWUDyhQIHnB2ee3puwPz@f4@RXghXj/ENFYj4XSeA29obeadBHQdgHPyQqkud42oROmrrbkkiHtoqBU9Q26TunDI0/NPHTYHQgGIYx3AoN44N4cbUQCFQc9QvPcSd2BhqWL4EfK7NL/hB@/Nj1OpWHdmJXxv1ELddvkx/zTGwP8ROfiq65AScjUCj6ib3DxJlmSR25dBs/j9/ROWU8MIpH2ZU2k8oVcEntMKXNpMgNFaNRqZQb5b7cN@wRDGBIh654caH7ZBuMQ@LRE3f3PfSzULpUSUPDLdTtLg2Dw0CljYfVN8obt4NiEWDvSnJZNk3dFIJCqbOulQeUwSPZxIMie4fQlct4IqPV@3CxjXCbQMjbu3jFZFA6NxN7FieOt/ef8nOL@XECGuXUXalbrqH/Z7ytxQWhHo/XPtdBsy6nSqOgVLYGTTIlwlJNUP1zpSH4iasrJRVIw0/nLNEePanUY81y8/2wZJaNgSmXCPyzCv1iI9GA9lhLp9OxdKoQS4vQ@0GvCMHwW4X3FfiJ8INwcbW@uBhWwwJjQiw1TCXEmCiLMVvf1oCoqWIRaQuVQq/wlCLR9LIabutMWotTHUFjLGEGQCD0mKHEemGIdSxLKgePRD@u5@JsJcsipY9AAnMp3E5sRNZXSu3wBmtEwAO6cPilWW6l5K/ScKTUKbPw@0gpvBgpW/JHPsagIhqLQEw@2liyBv1aajEnxm7jjfidKln2kriaLtYGS7W4CKVLfe6uCe8qQh1IfReAgYl/zh60gxL4uQ2V6xNjjWDsZ5RA/1NlqBixkC45IAHDkRpAvzB@yY/vWQuHQqvpUCgSKgHUIniT9InckogIgQQLPRFBbkFfXRQKaQgfC5uZHPARVU4MBO8CbcUy2EohELwN3N3erVXGiucLNhpJ0bj7@oSxbhRG10laZkw0gmyRXPFEBacWquVq97hacoCrmzQKTo63BrALfiwynlz82nXN6FrlPX9e4HI3pAiKaFNXa8O6s/iazgSC1m2A0492DSTXopXkRUAQsP05q1ThfDbCB@ffBslwLtu87aBYAolSfInklIq8WdXqkW8PFPU2n4lXaMQGfHN3F4xC4XE/TCVJxGwd0jaUQFDTHSeuZ9ggwEBmZ7MCjuFlZpwU3q@@z79/eXZ4drjDnqaK@WKeE@WCD6tjYkgMrbGnoDoqx9uBoPFZz4rfas9LwaIRyqyEMhPjgYuyYyYgjGwSruGqHvzqNRic1yPgKpfFdXG1qFjOolu4aA0M2Yysi7l0MZ0SI0Hr1z/4CZ5iTq8GHZeYWw3Wg85a3spqBF5ozSgtBivJoLM6topR4w6UuJoNWoXPwXQqHwjmX374zJj7iXIlTa6kW/tLt@OL3U5dyWkPYMI7@K/c1dbW7mg2485x4O3ujgdP/NNjfN0DMw6vv2@8bxS/ja/x/zW4LW4eOqUXclmBRYIfQNBYVjAQLIRg7BVi6Swei4yCZIWuqcY8zhNLd6U6zRTI72V5WaM/2VrGv/H7smWtwbv7KmMgy1ZEBgOOZPIi8goEa6FQyInpYOC3s1dyeSHAlheqLMTN3fFuGc3aeqfsQhNfG8TpqOWF@NbJ4eaL7VPsl2UNvxbNNg8PEhiEHzQeH5NsqbJkqiPni8YjhMLu/HTziOkmO9s6ojjndECWfGnWyUllaa9ddD7sFbtmYiKDC7HZZGolKWaZmC@mVovpHJNAzlloEMNxLWFURsXa1I0RHyCGNyMUeaGKMBi2r8AI3pKL7NnRPsUgWbK8sLX98pAdHuy/Tbi@3P90d@@EnRzunJ5Xj7ehHC@3T5hQPWF7JwI73zvdPTw7ZdWDtwyCj6sHp3vbJ4ggGUAZiYorJ5g3WmNr1shKolZr0ZBtwtvSW1eyPekvmYaURDvNk94afrVJxm@dTPoPNAXGg/7R4El1geuCDNFL7bYZwJO5Sost4PhvYRm0CjwY3EtZqyw7ePMpZWYXWWvlILTKWqkDLbO2ytSU88fUlX7mmC0uLl5ogtfB@IvhDUb9XnimA/zGedp7t70Qzq2wZRh4plci45CDw6OFlPu2cH58uiB6YcdbC2nvZW9nIeO9bMPbive2c761kPXeNqovFnLjaAebC6ve29b25kLeewMmXSiMcR5sLYipgEusa1D8Fuh7luGdvf1ttgxAkdJEKM4FomPKGwgRBmWNm0lBkrPl5ZueHqMxTXM0Bd2WvwTtgk9ALaC6WEO61mNsWTfgBoooAEO0gDeukMxuK@ZgRUtn0C0FbgMLWKAFLBDAL@ABfYRji2WWjjAIXujwPSFhbvkyxoQzi47hfmOxNVT5K8AMMTKdRsexIYbsfNg2sHDnoAx3aL60Q3vMCVSEnAqmEIngGc6Ds/19nphBWm5YIEjGVd45OHUDsEER4Y5FB19eObxaqC6QVguO1oIf3w3cTdRmYLo2kRRQzoWFFiCYpO61pMYYam0x3IeAePGFnw0BYAgGdwpc/PBqONzCsnZlu0UZiiAxtw93eAlxJ0OZTdZyhGGiRCkK5qdOPn9m7tuFPflqTr5qIY7bQc6zxfHxnJYRNoJ@C@6pYYIgCwkUcwE5JhqF2FAcCvOVawGIDj9uUMHNZQUSSoXYkyeUjzV4K4QoCYwXpRRZHEEQgUMwIh8i87K2SNmNLCSXcTMRbS0i67zYj3Czyc2RZwwGJOt0Rqdq1WuFXnUuaDAaLk0JZCeo08a6Bncm3YB3FI/AyTHWhGYSY26gmMNAHCHGmBxjHfCekqkNRQPOlc2xTHRZARoj1f7BFq8hbvmI/LkHlRjkXpEqDITFE2y@xOgLC01Tlq5KLhTIQ4ICvkWmCSMhONzD8Y63KNoyby/Ilhj7MTH3doouH/HYwA4OpxFZ0VgF5xWnuORZGQPN4HeQYfstA3rOkhxZNOpAeFzmgG1PwsXjHO7O5csvFGJ7uhSLX10KFMv3lmL7kcX43UoB3dqYRaAUIOLDgDcK0HSbrM30PBTQFxIKKs33QwEd6JiXoI1PIHhEfOhyx/HjXx8fOunidFOGdgs1yKUCjzL52pp8bU@@YvMFH4mtrbH0CvvMmugSc@BCowUsD442l5WTETuTrzSBVGayG6fjSWCeAvAcikoOhgw4K4xRgiQs/MSL1McPjZVZdaexd7B9OhmK@BJWw8l4z9Y1ldKITII5GcJwK4wvES9H4Q4Sgeub4SOeRozo2Tg5Pd6uvoxB/iJsbdwCpnUAuDktYaIEd24K4KvJLeiP2zEWPqmy5Qh7gjmLMWcyAl8enYSqWzKgujfF9sBIU1IpDuK9T7akILbIwJykhDALR9jniwvoUlOrTOwbnzP9jLaaabNRZhWVXY7H00EcKe8KmAPeNLmygZBtbuWzODexy1SKrZgZZss90LiHKXMWP5XrDvs26hbdo9WGToMyq8TwJDvKFscQDfSLk6rNw1ok9Y3IB@iLzRj8sDunScco6efInhTqKlg8L235a/PyJY12Mi9xnpc1SnQ2D791JmphuBSYOj5P9nx0wzYkPGHuBB7S9O4RepmBAJ@k8Zl1C@v4cSc7UiRzPChTGg0079tohC1Z7QCz6gOzBV0@qsuWA4YXhiZ4IDUkdEwGOuRB/WkyoK3giXA0ngq9zhRCNLgC3mhEMkwpBgJezixbNihXvmzgPBx@Dd2fIAywJ96hWvGkpi/HkaKjFe9I2B5cZLUJS1wcx8DqxeZ4g3ie9fXYdE6YxzZzwtDg4rworgWBOWGXg/68HIBguCfEOQM8J0TTD@dF4IasxgH1mo@ANT@B6/VwZH7VQ7uarHGfJTKi/6k5kB2zWnuHPhYE5dLhQF9dB7dkYNqWgh/SmEbkWSGAmOFhxGcQwWOryJiTJKulKNPoXUwOIjrRS9@KYMNiqwdYvxHT@UjMh9CHsc2NCd@Hk/mQQg7nIAmyE@J9d/rU8lAjC07jHcdPoD0PrQ3Du3EE3XgAHkPHsFj5LvACmmLzQjxmntPkxuiKs4xD/jipj9UvThituw/aLYQY8RP0d00@/rXJx33pY5v8XkmXWW0yH/Wo770IHuMyug38eyXk5noytchXldjPNbJ8dQ/7onEhXzLcqMhksh4aRwJ5POUWhdCjxyOFBOLyI/oK@ULV55g8mBd73P8sl1lc9OJwiTduDTQf7ct8AM2hNBpoR7jRIAOSjQbOLDUaAk@BOl7s8PydrtPYeFgCtNSGTqFhIS4JMSEer55s7u3FFU2I8W8TlAXL1k25gXbghBguZJcFElgNhOnJqlEWnC2IksUotnB/GlVfGlDALydCQDyVPY0SGRsI/nJyLX@R9EcUSZ9KbGy09BGpHVNqaJ/hoZRMbv3PTWiTDNShxT9TVlDQ8K8uID/oHbLkMmFABKf0nSzwdC2a6bPQbAvPEj0a6OfUNdo/2VdoVE2zfYJr0EiYsT/ktHac6kEEY07l3Ccc0VfYGBm3a8uOnkXTQwlhbNjUyVjCKamP310FjduDGXdok0aOnPzG3LlJC6cxp7I6Fiy6gYWvCWgDCSrgSDfg7tlBArdnCQncaAsJvVxRB240hIQxOo7DsYkELrKKBE9gb2FshLUvDZX@ACdu/JY2HE1unC3s8rEk1OtT4KT04xRFiISK1qzDDt5IVCgKUHSLLDBNW2FC@HmGmCL1wKyQJbPhmE2f6jAP6VzTTpHY76GSfIoYimbLyQ3EjQlM4EoIxRWLdRh8@njHFTGoPk/56XzWExFBSWJe/HF/5TPkVJ4YXiBFYPDAMzOOwGeZ/F87JeU@UvRUkHGN@aG44jYn37h7@N6M@zG4ilok8MBI6v834yR/lfxXOlT6/35QNDP0@SceyjwwhPnq0crvcVjw3xT6/6bQfw@F/vemzd@jkk@jnG3xU@r6F9Xwr1e/SOaNoNswu9c49Zb@PnrY70kRWP0qPcDNdU18SBf4cv/sokn7u/Xv2UsHfps8befOd/RqtXraF83jZ9VutVc9RptZG6n96PnlysbWzcazjXZ1a6v7vLt5IL/KV1f2jRdv8m@fdT59lEF73z18/u6TarR6gTfHxs25fHSTkfNWdTD4uLc7snc3zvqbJ9m3qzepbTXb2ZA/bqnW1svTNy9On2VPojcfnx89/9RP9a2jTkoq9DO7L3OvN0fnWiB7rZy1d/aVw/5Je/ss3d/fUt7uRDdT@yeFV2Jqf/vmXWbzJppNJfeMF4fPjs8um9vv1OO9/bftzY@6lPt4dWPsJduFzubl8evAYeaVuPvx8LC7nS48203ebHWMdiq9q5rZyzfHRxtnb3d7L6Tt/k72rPDmcnSU6716dW0fRLsr57nBS2slqlVfvUq/0J5dX28fB5qSfmpm5HP9lWjc3Bzphf6q/OJgt9t/ZYpa8jD7OnrSP73Z2t5QP64OM2dvz1/drJy8Hbx89fzdYUo5OWluSzmj2U6fXJ6uBFr9zF70@mz7LC89a5@/6l/v7WbfbiVf9uSDavtIvXrW3X2nnxzt71Uz1kAT9zev1bfPepcvr7Y291T96ErVqivJrHrafnt4GDh7rjS35N031vPqZe9tMrtxtfI22jaenV5@6l093zg5O8ynh0ejlL5pHTd3O8Ot41w6n2ypH48/dfSX4tmraO768nlaeVv9ZAcyn0bZwr76Vu5rz6Ot7rvhRzUZPRPFzXd7n96@Pdm9NptV7ezj653jS/NlWzu0DlPHz1@8bKpXefvSeKednIit1DP56mU0JQWGZ7sW1JF8KmVXT/v7r4zhlv7xeO@dlfsUvT6/yshbV8evqx@PU80bzXijmftKfzPVPpSqr3V7ezB81ipcn13tqvsfD623gZfbYja7o3esjc7rlcKb5LNo5@rZmw3xZJg60I47Kznz4PWrc0XZ7r05@3Tcyu68NvJ9W@u@@nTW345u7w97n@R8qqmevL3SAmfZk@Oj9I32QunbO7vHL3P2YWr/9VF7dyRWX8nijba6OcpuDc1c5nzrjfn2alczkm@Vj4OjlHwdbb817JVXSrPTeq20@i8CJ897ZwdHr2/2sjnzWV9TNo7yqYP93c2DbnvlxWjv5WB7v3nZfrb3Rn5jnOau0tsb57mtNycZ@/TqhV1oXfczR/noqdq3u2fRwPNBb7B6dG5@fD18t1LtN@XMsfpWH62K/c3nRnr4urp9@Kl7dWToB@JOepQ829ev1NSn05tPu1auOormh2d2X7dPxWFWfBXI3Hwy7OfG81cnhxvPD989l1YU5Vy6PHndTmXO8kmlZ2b2crln4vZOp/@xX5DFT1svM1Km34ta@1fJ9mb77PX5lXrZf9G/bAXyBau1sfduIOnbzbSYervR2c7K@xv7p6J81n1xsrJ1kDp60z46@zg8bW@@GZy9PlRS25fPC/vdlTfHrwsvVt@dWqfSuf7mhXkQGOYzuiXmCtmbzEkhf9gzTzLnlwX73YvL3IZ63hSf76X78o5ivsmP8lfGp95N9@ZETjW7z7Y@SsedbZCkZ0cpKTu4OhieBDKvT/vXq8ZG9O1V68UbTVTz58pq8vTjZeGq13txs9VaOa9@@ihln13KhZOdZFPdyT6LHm@@Orrsbp1/yq@0Uxv7r6U3w@2e/TbwalfZuiycXx0OR@KrnZNRv5rS1Oz1yXn2@lTfODnfPcn3XjbNTnP3sgeyoT86u7wZXO/Kq73hTf5F7/K1lNp/k9/UrJWjVOC5vNdvH5@@eFONdtJywb4@fHtgnOfPh9mXef28oB/mlRfVzrPhq8POdmrVUM5Ph2fbveTGptLPg0w5Us/MzcNXu@/OnxupQFrLbXza1LOrH6PXw7e58@RRdH/wtnWa7p@b5u4bxdx5c3305sVJdS@61xw9O7qSDt9uZ08ONjet59EdJSePdjM3VnUzo3b0gNXfGB4MTaOQeXe134WeQG8X2s9OM@eaVa12bvbyJ9vV6jOrufdcGg6fdVahj8Br@/y1Xg78lttDDHBTiPwhcYMqgb7VbepDkJf8NGOAzqMF6DxagJ9Aoy3YfO/yb5PLgVP/wQs8ducYqR80QVljbR2VhwTb84wW4zdLYqyvQ3QFXS3doCeidY6YtHHAp8Kd5qvwvCR9f1QeGqqu4Oeg8NMUOCY1x58KTAQONdYf4XjTlvv8OIiCX3RybAzT1yz4h7PIxmlgodVi7ldaE2RB1/tm6wdQIAytGyeTyV0Wj7c6qtS1wKG2yfUhcOKZ9McUVEXCyQ9MQtxvSGIq62xNpS8rYuZO8UNUB88YfsEOt8G6Iw4JlIkR2ZnBSSqyNSPjlxwt5VpWR/TxE7mdCPAdn4/aBen3w73hk35k53VqbyioG7I5tQHU4BHdldbk8lO09fN0OekssaIy1JDMpmLjd8Ib/FRGg6fo7nkzJvce0mFmZ4GWK0ao2ZCFZO7sS0N8m4qFFKM96uNDhbifDlIEFdXdbbi8bBBK2nfF@IsP87JxP26l3/19oZ7A3VbkCbw60GoAtKIF6Zk1@28s2uToAZUCfLF@@83eacP5Qg7fYjhxkuueHZc@KpfcN6PES@DLv5Pz2W2ZuMMAso/TjtzAOBT1Wue8LNC@R9weCbWNI@zxbssEcA3tNEBsBu1Gqa3U@Q7CFG3dcwnuxXnCOeGJL1dPxgRdcDZUeDzwyHh8gyYHmS0vIu6YskwAtJvTPXoytdnv98x799RMU5W0K3SV@FZZGC@YLV9l0bc/fOXAqSyvLM7@SX6GD8oNUb1tsOOMCqZXLQTgbIh1q/lMw@ZM@@0xDq9hL2mcH8M0vFGXquqt8Dh42d1yw8sWcVPi8FNJHeJMYgd31urmiCeE0zPhUglAcJ8OyQRZc3er@kpdHlMD0dGmHl8ugG9LrhdaTpDH@Yyxh3PLk1okdqAdQPOzyjcDIVTNy1adJ3W/LAR6R/yFmYg6Jo67hQicyWVm6wYQoeNwHHRjxCN8d@oMVfhOL4@LGKdTLVWHf7bufynyjbvYoPCMPkMREsFmjCP0qcx5mUbQitd0MKkx61FF4Q5urEKFeJEpMMJHf6ZEoxP15ENeU5BuIosStcNzQkEMeSVySO/QnmBoTxzUBt@Kyzp8BxendWCKRGuQ0OfPXoOBV48bj9zzosAS/DyozixkcM6ZvC07BC25724j9NwUMiaKJ1XvZvfS02FZGIDrN4YylNUwCMwGfvnHYODlbFkyDO4gCG/7EnhjZVPeHXm1uBiGWDWCS@br7AkLi2tr4dV4mLy@yUciXmN0oqd90X2RQUhXKiycXg5n3MgrGBlQZiYRrMxHkOYIVpbDoosg7SAQs4CBqxiE5BuW51w7iTjvQ@zhrU/C4PeD5qS@nI6K9bW1PO7x9HlORU7Pz/pyJpqGyBz1QnQyhKPlAT7/@mSJAHkm7etHfChWohlAwZOOTgaMU50K8BL1p7lSn9s5/d6UF/echtv5UHT8jKls1vJYXuRUvindYOA2bNPxxE/JGfRBubEfZ@llZHPQEahJQmo9GQ9NxfgHBZ1OC@hXmuoVfYcjCALFABHBxaPE2OVDfV3z6zs7BO7QBB8vc4yJMZaHYQhIFJAYeYgMIoRooHQbrb7hwUFXnI/wHd@8A6NEDnDFGc8PQD2h2u@mRGKMkw9XuAGf80E36kM4fcMQobG/t4GP19vHuGN27@AZVOECliPGxne3mIsco1fETUnjH5lRbAWyALKND2icsvKqmkwfPd30HWwucgd@GjuPSKVDCMYjO9oh8YViNxTdwcZJ6fKRbBMd6ZtnHkA@UoJxBruRmaQiOUb8W815/mk0OvRGsYlU4PAiOhlECiHNTo@rByc7h8cviXJHjer@0W4VMcMAsyWZbUYf78EGommyyjtVj54B7H67@MF7LJPUdL80o6B9DYLlX4HkxAPABoU0yHc6R1hezvQz8Nx7XgSSKB40KBWNtmzMwY17Vz0wpzDWHIS8Fnmuna7QydO8npA6vNme0JWjFZR0REtdtrSQDYxNHzOSNC5Pki6@DRhl0pcgqeWiHtUlfjH5p@8yafoeNvKRNTBwdVhuC37yS62WbJGBhjH1AaWsdigRR7L4CAU@80s/lh/8bIrX9zo46HOg1OmmPL13rOZOKougPXLafS8d16cgcSyujnTrqpWkFjkp889zT6iOyqTKeF9iPLVLntolpMYFLrucVsiUeu1yQhGbRx7FJc8l141dzYyrJ95Wcqq5DjR6q4eGlGguhEsdqjCsJrIaoo8mZN0Tt8qeuK143BLnK3cPK2UOYSc1MqfDGfefzoC53QayhWfmNujkCo2@BibWP3/R5Bt8oZ6SH3RyhxgET5zSAHXahXPFJ56hupczEBNIQzotU3OSq1On4uELOwhZ3M1PxKdr0ClMZ1ZA0UBajA@nOWUlVVK3nIGizxPFqtMLm223kRPkuDMz29MHuhAIffmBw/GpBH6MjyeURyd9SrRMqJFDxjorBXBdNR6HCBE@r0E6DYhbLANlT7HnFyM/WwyncK5OpvATMCjqHLfIRQGCfoZxD/i6iZfmlttXDvcwHEaO@AqWKjknKNwTvWdHLCNmMr7jv4fnByyXG58ORgNtbCWdGh85RlNtLFcIfK95svF8AudHbDhOhSJbIc/g0B10QVlVoRHzR1vBrh/zxofFQ/4YlTzlapmPYC1HHDtdg8X6AwunKJmEI3Q8WikOxURgAYQizQE7Xzl1O28A7A4kU9JsmZ@xREHurOxighQRdVjZhHI1oWXgtjGU@H00lGcNTJlPAINPW2/RJknEQfGgpgd92o0UQ4XhWjbRDIBiOwf9F0jmOOzARUOFM4Hr6QqHissbnISOSKAWjZMsnIzULSP1@NSL40qTunK6n6Jcnu6L1KW5H0zGDBB5HVYhGnN3YMEh8Ew3Q@PxZeercW6T9IDHon/e1OBsJ8MHp@443EHD@5jZkb9SnzMZQ9zV8vdBQ2cTE6GiMtUj7hk4kgDuEaiWOw/BgegxrFP3RLj4aBQpCOOXtsLnwhnJCNIiqJeiLsVErsNdOo59Pgpe8D4ZT/xchtYXcXYGjJwDc97xSAcCWT7CIZyzkdMQ2D45xNCPA3LBG@pycrz/YIg4vPNuKL6JQ9xROLojzrgAEfBxLaldPP/8TNr8UjhtlBLlR9Kmc0pBEV9bng/Gi@yAYel8YJApkkfLntEbDnZ2ND735gJS7mlC6qHMT6T22Mw7yc0ATVDikVn3CHHnzNXNQwqR@/q1zBepnG01jprpqx@uJEElOoxAPEvt3pmqcGjgSgWeu6YvBteZ3TiuJKEQ59DvrMhxoDzHcto9DuwKdG@ac3yud15BOSe7RXWLSTVIn21XFYO6xsmyOs3CX9a4OFvYVV9h3VPGE4V1IrnlnLXvoIGjo@o33P4CdiiCc3JZ@KYdY9@0cTHE8fH3US415sm/ybPOvgb5vjxukV75vLzSoVnvhbdVZ@0QRbuf3zEe4k25jRy/201dgIjgulZyN9fzWAsLjjoDSs9EvHTEmXb22NlF0emAvKat@miSdz/tYhpzDGEps285HuqCPsnmBLAL9pnkPGYg4sF2FCipD9bHRY5knmikLndgQDTq9Gflidng8QHqexnRj8WRnb4jyg/GJ5kym4sRhvFucj4ON4rT3Y/bf8mfkdG9GUFy0BqR09d5a0bcJMLd77oyOtbdDEdzA73LSMPto6OIOfpbNuXqAWFjrC94owM@HvDrBo6i7SqDOLEFCjyMjfnR6BiD1O@FH1sY@cgX@PBoHsQkCyD@aGRqwi@QeA7TvmGR4RvEzGaTaocoavA6mcw3VSRNhHjYeTGeGDVElkzHcRmQO6PiTKkm0DE65EyzcSVu/INUWTSpTuNUv/UPrPhlLDwuWY7HWQYeDnZ3OxAKpW@oMj@5I@43qod7nmkr1rNto5hMypaOXlZCN7vJG@VKSXLAwIljtiouD7Cdo5EqHtLYPoOuDA1O2Ql2IvPNCqj3olr2gYaT8iDyASOhBSwNgDsd0Hi1lowfqrFvcP@Ag8BK@DMLwZIFeriusZGuN8e5l5yTOTwDMcq7BZnvAmEGzQRkINmSbEseyUmMmGyqcOtLaBg7CUPyJJYweajJ@xD7BJqEnLiUrqXAli9jdHJ6KlWyYReI49wRhdj4nXfaPYJzCDbui2RNHerG25/qDBLIwKWuqSOmoQmALmC6RmiQKpAUct4NFJN23DqLOrTlQaZxxEqqkCNhbzk9HMXD/juRgLBsJMC/UVzE8x2WjuxiyrQ3laJP7GmZ2pPBG@bkJgo@zp/0a6Fxri/v0/C2eCSTvri69ph9H/P2eJD9LyD7fTs/kkmcHjVUacSEG4lMkrPNldVUrohjLaWrERtia0EjOj6NXR6iQW4LNwZgP@7GVeVrWWUZrMbXijUAwBN7AEUKBA1T6vYlFzCcKTJMxmeji8bXEyf6x0G6rk76dPDcBBuPqPFkGmPiGBud4HJ6FSSm4@30C3IEpBbc1nHLs64brAiOttwcdKkzwHNZbgw8HSXFmhhBilTCzcg6PIvwhKyTpWtox9j4y579KtxPpCusBs28ztwFCqEUoFJA0y/z3Jfc@NhzIJhvRQc6bL6qAT3CMms4g1E@SwDQ2IeFOZzF5z1p8dwFaet7hzhrQwnyzcVuCBbRcCxF3runZJn59pSASEB7U8iYZAIrmXRnRkJV/Gaz@7IR4qE0axTm7vEUEe/1lj1yuPsXOnz3yRrZBGNkJJTIGSm5u@rFErtzAXEPCGo4uLMkHnJ3DqCGaeLazHhHCpBecEdhD6H1ZSDzBUiqOGQz7Jd8xeAbvOt8tstRQaaDxbq7hgX@5VTJpQb/xLtX/@PFrCe8Nheo4Iv0wfhb5qjTQosvxNAqibPANJFX7LwcHiHu4LicLj7M@YE8JrnBmU2kSdOYN6HKM8rnXEFYoM4Zpy4lxoasi7PvfPgUYyPnFW3sB7gh7VRsVBZLnrVtWRv0b3EwEuNRBkYMge@YDNK@FMC7M6IzeeJe64ZegsQ6CvIACQr0qrn@OLVxm4ox8a5EKbfos21cxIMeMcv7c/diXWiIr1iDoQj913k3UfymLcR4erhkQA7RdaTrsXFqnIherocj/So8jI1AdDA8j1RxRh3odibn6XXkCyIbJc46jSNgcB62IeG6YwNpF3YtkLHGsAwDpMaojHN43P4XKry8WZABGYQvMgCMxxEQRqjMVXYpnMgMom8YjWI4DOomwwdGEUfZbvyZcKw9ws/j@/HfjY3kER0aw1hjFHH3pUCMxmiZSOBtT7mbKS5l73co70x@p8o7Qw@vvPfQwyvvLD2/V3m9GeM3VBDoYuiBYxwcsq/DiBqgPU8@T7HO0DM17qG23k7HHhj4DaWp2PTti9nYumHoFppcn58DnuacTFC4zx/SXOdpFMENA@Qknz4S8yloevgVAyvAm7ipo74YJjd@Z5P3X6BPqnxu2@mjyQMxF2hG33uNT71DAhGnK/F7uSLRKx8mxWUqVydAbbui/cVl5kuq5GWcCsrHYIwie6WPMP7qw@ErOm1fhNy4UZBQETYvygD1Dow3HQX95kdxqO7Ix8lYSHU2N5ZbiRjb2V3pakIkdoQ9Pkoaa92Cb62pQdIZ2NWnT3jjWG@@dxh1GZxXBs30hqJuLw1Dsb0OzbZt8o3Y7MiZncJjT6DC2z1TH3R7DA1FoQ6IsHxLeUdH7R61S9Dq8eOqA7RVU3S3xYXHxffmj5PszGAwyKfz89hyXx6xTVT8myOcS@ZzAWFfN@HssFpYcHWnhfGU9gJJeg@4zif6@IzDOHmqM18GtpAfIAsvcSYOkj8mdpqTsNuJxUVPAxEk20Z7/6hZK7wIWPxxNAOXYcYRUQNwbXyRsvL/tvdtzW0kWXrPwq8ogd0NQMSVupGCik1JZE9rLYkyRU3PBMXGFIACWRKIwqAKItAUJ7y@O@xwxHrHs97xXsL2ztphv@46dr0R9oPfe/7D/oL9B@PznZOZlVUokJS6Z8Z2tDpaQmWePHk7mXlO5rlcM6D5jRUytlrLrbOb@4RIJa@1zdxGshlqtpFdH1d9zQsaJ7eI2bsbag5qR2u2/V/D/Jla5fWa5P5LSJMq1VRZZTifhFwoRxOzA9O8E7gvh2cNoVSSwAnls3AC2XBezcV8ivs4Xl3eKcleLCoDbrWumnNM8uxbKBrlluYXt2OPpopNB4CIWsCslbyd4b0M8epQ@imLo6awCMARs3LwOyvNCHt4ZdaFF0diEvZ8vx@BZfVAK9zOMswb1HLVr4T9wDuChEiSut56dXP4PpqlxeOgJ1YZj56jKRP/x9NgIsI2WlOnuWS9HyKFR8d@7w3DIixTgr0WjGo0bKO4Fg6c6MdTb4Irh3DirJaigtrj5aTZU5o4WT5KbVDtFDBTnrvIhFjAYD/hCjJDVvq@Dlc1es9jZR1ECSlFKkaHujPC2Np3P7g1qTu0X5kLGTqeh8pCN4gYjyV@V53BdIi9OBzXkYedMN1Z@wuMZfe6K04MU920PlJAsrGmcy2MSg1lYjCU@RhXJ7HsNJeDbyxAo6olwDWBNjKWNb5m0GgoU@OWet5ho6Dk/oKy@f68DHqLNMwAuhYTX4kQKNOsVLmSRbR8FC9iHYWjmo1ZwBYRExzAKledP/c3NH8OGKAR9h7aYGD@jhvGnofLSm66kj5ppXMvQciqK7QPnEyHsTfyw2k0nP@6CaFwjcOQKt6Zkub8@UP1mWbHIYaJdNZAMADncWOX1d2gmwBBnTbvtSf3kFPcV1sNJu4kVOesM1RmMFFVxxLCM1F5H3lPVB4OR60TkMmBywTc9EBNIGYbr6qoDdDWyeZio7jO5bSCndeLp7yJHodQroBO6RT3QdDxmMBEjKcEGzb6AuTh2J9IZURt83Dq6POZ6DVx9UkbZOJrM6BK1dHH@LE3o1ugezlICA9wW6igcnjkW2Vo@6WGEzjfHVG79fHW9dUdBQ43ed1CkFHUwNXSv8AdiA1cUuEH1yavcLjzRZXAnSnXhFsBWmzWLZno2ZevK/m@ogX9jP4Ts8z6rkvDCkEp3X68JLBWxeK1nBZggzYrWpQDF5oa92FhQeuSQA@Cw@su3lpEa4PvzjCLp0QgvjfpHVOXaL4CEEw84XHqB30eNpLhcO1tXJlHDqFHtKSKMNCj6UkXLmkGPF7GTJPfPXBJTiDlBHWFa05MLwPe4YJVoudXUPXk@@N@xawtqYrlEgg/BGjukXCCqjbx/aUaGHwnmk1mdAZl9YmrkDUMC74PVCLclCh/9AtZa4fac70R@dbaWYytCzBWksuzjEkYLrxiS8XpNJy8kZcjXLvxzh97Ad974y1QFJZRSN/o4ZE/SvLkJUNfziVhTXg942A59uLLL3k1NcW0KQ7FoEcMp5IBlje8dqK0bLSRm0JbtIX15AaqobKgGSVl5eVSNnZDPPrNVe4QxTaoaZtuqbF27aUgc62uMsWubTIcKO4qRRsKUlEEoHXLcf2uriR1HTVGw1DSeJFxuPGrrgZrK3Onmp1yDvFf2qmHT9GKP9ps6tUo9OG6Qh1JHUZJuGep6t7Q5g2iT5Yafg4I7JoADh82brxjyHVq25kp/S62tJqJhte1jPztSI8PwJJeuzZ/n9HhsTBq4smdfJGpWS0DljuMMuCa0EZGytMb40CWfo6pilLylHAHdLw7CKagzDfo074Mj@KKea5XCzSK61HMtGOd9DXZfYi@89adN4xC5cqMD1YpFPF74fu9xOgVKNWrddedDtAUvPRTmcRAZdE65frAbDmsmisP/jJSDM56h1PgkPVfsbQFtUN9sVohKDZZUS/8quCBvhMHeqVGPVB3ZNID50ZHVav6oF0YoRP84G25s2Gp6nsT/4j@2QvQon5UAr9kXr7rhW25THy@@/jZ/s5eZ2/n@zt7L3a4JCvyG4Pi6bjBN2XRKZx7jxTeUpRyiFP4YhLQOY4Th@MsQQJ/0Qvj2PmMxF2fxPE3HpX0pn5h6Zv72pPleS8jf3JPyu8LM8/G96xpHAUwEZpCVYn6dyoCuDwPl6OKED@dgeyQClqvQ3gykLhQBeyZtJlLDvZPrKRuyBEQGUJZNuBICQfxKThAJU2k35jppBn2aTX7daVjq6Fx5ZD4SzAOEcAAUD60bud1Dr5ur1UaeJ94TrCRaKtETSbZ@1HTeS7VbnO1zrb0CzykNwxHRwXlPcFqAXNudGhVEdr9nh5iNgqiKqC3AE@BGGnpkXSoAfmg0ao3G9@eS4PkEfu35K3gA0zyP9DOe9FOPzd@Up7Zvo4BYPE45xkbulTYpFwLuvxoTWmDukxFa6qiDzMnX25NrtDf/C1bkC8xIFetu/WbMRr/du25r2xm/Y19LPzmzXByCThllaPJN1fF9PzbM9j5f8Vq5P3MRS6zovjOdCLfdEIFVHsf44nSjRJrH4PzeLwrF/a4ajLXP5HW7lbhjDI8md61Uoq2JoJNWmk@iUejNJGvpkSf0qBPqZX/2tThl/c1xxYg6W6@2vF79Noyjkh1tPlemvAmUM8lKu62tv55qv26XlttHyrtkzl4z@QiDWtONTetIs27zbt3TkoNXCxdRMeXyV9pmBvzFu1U3rqM08ro6uzQd2ZSMqP@LpeCOaVNkLdYxciS8FrpEHOKWm2bRAXXbKcU4pUcVdG4zhfHL6O2noxgclnKTsTsS3zV1vINjA0CUfHZANuDSnaOUiiTy9hlKNNTo@diWWVqoS3YhJgX@P9frK0MCYqBx3dGVr9FI6vvrEa@sxr5zmrkIquRleuNaTRpdINRg1izoVM7Je6/sEILanvX@eLzB/vO/uc7zmcvH/0954e7L50vHjyjlF3n@cuHTx4/cuj/nWcvdhwuYP58359A5d6hqd/2ez7fzq81m7ccxrwQoPyW88I7cT4Pe/5bIp77kXeydSwf9ZEfb0qpnbf@ZB7Kc9AYyiyxsprguyJ5a9I3TrC47hIln@AdUfvyRBvZm2ckN0tse8Hh0I0Bt7ztMQ/Celz8rGSMNgg@pFRC48mTLOtO42mdmZZ@3VEDZ/689wgSU/j0hfPg2TYifW4/3n@8@@yF89nuHn0@/yHc7Djbj@E25uFLZDHg093tx589fvSAE6QBzbqDuzU2WL@oCXWA86j03gymCA82hFSovlJevVcKhVGorSIipzQdJe57@kRSeHcXZ6dtdtFe/ujB3ve@D67G/7FTLCLIpeVQXVkgfNSE0QjVpqJot8WZOljLWks2pJO58xGy2wW@A@LfVUcjr/A7ceA7xUe4RsSDNMfNFoZNo6aKrhNuoNKOYF2HIzCUStX7jHKTauPbA10bLlYH@gNFt5RjVsiRK9pLa8RIEZzx8agnYXR1AtG9aHVztfFEAHAhpBIEAHcwSIi9N/5jXJI4txXENIbgTwl3JOH1yfizU3CNMHBVCQ8lEMi6apPMG08pAhx5wUjmMWXWJLsDx0jhIhHDw0nOcKivXFkljvh/9caGV1mCLNIuOKCVrYWK5NmNqIH29mNvEEdO2a3gNphEEH8UiKbW0dAjcY/vhScwWHoLNQKudt3Fn03tqF4znByIU4sw3bmTbocpt60Ofv@q5ajkw4UaobfHnYbClIr/dGkDHi404EPQEKKavV/ArdA4ZsaW0YQDRcrlKCSKJJHP@Uk6qlHYn/b8VAEl65RfB199VVGDXE2KWCo@3DqjYYdQD3gIOYUPKnZzQUIMa0oe4zVK5rCc7kHyNnwCZYgJGvgjPbiqNlt40DUqTRxVKfj5JbV2PTaGu7RWpnjRDTbb19j4jOLn70jM8viZpAsx2UhzEfw5Q4kBnp0mcPMycKBYNI@5JRLcoZDsHT9xosbBl@vu5vbDV7Wf/Kh62Ggcybbg9eXxQpQS5ZmFRXJaHkZ3krUB9UpTSAvRtIvSWp9Rdkusco2MGJfjgJjvrU7b5Mm16mL6iONlpdM58d07V0rV2N6ESQiRZJLdreoc6CqrXObQqSgEyd5JjYVnXZ1SZZxmv95CXHvMQptGZIR9hNVr7LBqrF9jebvGgx7tLAXFp8l0G/wVHYtcURT/Kdvz0fiy/NBd3aw0NBQvJjOcZb1FVzXmVkX16hzTy@fVArrti9HR/n11dOsXtk6Oh/fCtn0htvdqW211OS45lixcV0f7kwvQyuH2QWip79XliOWQXMRmKN0QZ/WjFU3zl9T4o4W547VHaHD2IqKqQWrVNh0N4SGuLJfi1DQuULHRJAzRi/3tnb09p7iDW7Z7VJb2PW/UY/tSbIPAfV17OhI7ZN7s6oZpMmGCDPOkU87FvDRd7UWLOXfwlmwVigepqvEwm4WJ2kuSyUxZR8jJwiwEDK9lQ9Qjl27dmd6DogOF@PwAmlBOMmlWBwu53VyRw0ec7PMmk4xbVXjj6E0wNsyMP1POuviqejK3EWlGGMeBd4SX7/z5@0L443u6HmGw/B9PucNQwu/BX77zgioe46W4np7BC6ZFTynrrDCVruixY7O8NIf9zQnKxGI/V7ywta0r5lg1Tfjjj6xIdsyfbuGdf64yeyfqvlNv8Zxy357QSnLoldNHEDGZJAY7WzZVUPHDc3WE8WiYc9I1DLm91j7i1hzoVnI0M4W7vRzoY@Lgb9/Jbg/Zqmi3vbCq2rdTlZwSqZqsuFuLNehMwnzn9u2bl@HO9kIXr31T3HKGZPfP@GT81rNQRvOIVYWIch8/q@r8hAAuGDqXpMB@WS@YTEFidXLOlFTf@TCy20dtOZ3AFo8as/tyv4r7omytFWeWaVs@djmRbOwMstAHawmbjsqqWRj984ure8hB3S6p7/r71yeLDUC4Dz//lYTJ3AvH2CqJEZ90xCsqieT3ImjFxSghwQeNp18rBuaWjmN5IPHmtuSFGzbSUuNWHL6BXr@OnKlimxXxDFU/8cZn73DB9Y6vTCUPNgGqbFB1tl6LjopE1tzqh6xEMDChLLeklek02ubfduzgm/egPsh5AmA9YLpmAEuflBySe@7hVkGHmiytShrxJyapJklEqzFkD5N@Q9JhlxCMh3OT3pD0vo/Acyb1vsJy6pmIl6VNBZmNkFkqKmC@qw0G8w4Pu8n@VLKJjTFJH6vGkGw5DE3qdUmFTpVOOlBlp0nSoSSRJGWSVhQUDqYgtmkp8v03HZ5kFW2OEJaqzigYHtaV/tSnZSU7VpQJRywTSeX9Ub/Ak8IxTw0qfSRswbWsIqGDreCwzgqUagOCTJZMrCykrSApYANTuhX6UohKinED8LdqhGqqTbyo@WDrNSh84ke9qe/szCDj69iImirZMciKs/Ns29n9zNnbfb6TRo0Wd8CjcCmtsMehmFXDuDt6yVZpwsNpfNyRRP2ZzT31JVejkG8DNAonFpB8ZnN1BYziEMvSOXvXf@cc0OE9NpNS7lcO1aTrHps@1HvhdBSfvZu94@mdEadXJxL41Dmv45Lg04VhUStRcdiaHPgtDmEhwVd2tFuFpBZO4VpmyjdHqCyuM2u@cq6wFcz@SVNHK5M36SQgJ22T2AlCsDz3VHxLGo7ecRJwk9@yXadczjYMh1K9vpC86tw1gRt9O@JuurIrVrK6rJKNpBKhMIOnHiGOaFJbxemHzrvgna4sOVRw9K9npR0z2vDdrKbROmJ42aVgmodWtrxKWH3uF9K/FhacmkEnHW9UvW7IgkCQ92Q3d4XGU2BM3wtgZnPQYLKAFuB4FaQAZZksAHL5RYyd/FYmSy@nSH6Lk/W42JwltSTocork15I0Oj0VyVrPzEYvJO5MApLgR4cEQet8zZ05IpuFipctVidbUJEiizMdqbMs/1Ry6tDbtEAQPR7qn61DMb1xSnaxC@HTI2K3QHXeGhDsQexOBceand7KpttHkrNpFc9CWI3KABPOzEl1@VyIJ5FU0ikstWRZsdGWigYOXksdjbTlHFqgTEJLQGtpUFk1CSyBAoS5OJwsFqisxDToaj6oRfwMb2PNtNVajQZ0NR/UWh8LWGt5WNOgq1nQhX2NN8r02BuG9kb54smrLOFjbXRWVf7M701jOWm00wpaQzEtD5vRUtD94CiIP3USRot/1ak9INpb68ojtk4jAf/2XcP6cAHNattNUNUmCLFbWLxUkFOxXEfZ7FvCmBvmMQUvIa7xPm6BHjCEPQ2OeGBSDdFMhhJo9CmmWTF7aKTULHbabIzkFJ2VM/o8B/d7sHIm4o5Efi9Wi5XzojSrndpFqU86WclH9@/rsajHYSdwcv@0VeMZRzh20jjqSdIFf1I4prFJxRVHdRj25LKzClxtLawdUDoEcH7YyeDAa8piX3RBQnN4eTvwoLKIA01YdS7qlI1DC1WLOG5cGYcW2BZx1K7eDpan8vry8ZVxiCCYh6NxZRygwMUxLa6cEYJz@buYR2qp8YBZlEr1qt00aRicXuqrm@2LFlUd2AsyhhT8LPOV1w7FmNu0PrTEoCuNB4SOxfEoB7KSNuko5p27KRfMLZSsLKwXEW45VW5grZXXdj6K4j4dBPXB0KzvnMWfEdEzlyQKId97QIip944nJCJhNutK@tAMCOOk9nc6UM3qdPhm6Pne7vf2HjztPHvwFELUiuxRuL6Btgyr6zTra4hnL7ctHdYpch2oWqAbBd6HrTxun0Kzw6cIR45FqZUzC@68KAwUanL5vqg@8k@dzyiLg9Yv4ARk3dzN0PSUuQ1mUy/W3hYrCaR9guleKXltk1rCMEInqiUMYyUXLGFLyr8aiYbKq9GrWAC7zoHYZEaHdntfwXDJKug4tbev4u/7ky50SWrGaanMIlTwIbuxcyqoXKgb9ASDNYG/ajSch9oprrJf84Y9uLydDtjx7Ukw9E66fa8@Ph4XBpGr3NOUS4MITi4LUKZ6vL@z96LzHHG6dh6x5QT@tDlv//HTnd2X@8h5QVk3VfLO3t7uXocV1PdePt@Hx9BMUtEGVFgSMJWQAnq2@/mDJxaMfBdVI8UgJCJ5k/5RrnyqTjDuzPjvOZt5VEUVosNBeNhMBUU5rerEwYkfTnXwNvif0Ad8FZYneJShunRUY3ZIU8b1p8pLfJ2eW1Dcjsl0HDMoa8CXMyNRSZcQmJPoCAXYF1FEfDtr09flRhl5MOQLx@VMWRjIoFhB2XcNIl4dWCYv5qNeWaNTjjyrZ/6IIPHaVJrGg9p66bwCr5JjVhrKFi416ORosHPUUn5JNYJKK71gBTGyr13bBW3wTlBsUcKTkFimcAF5QWw7q6tB5axgB4hSWbSrSvyoM8eyoU/DqPg116w5EremoudL9YNAzC9lgWNoRD6f249STGDqfYqNOQ5geW7GjP/VnZUb5rKZnTK/TyV23XVojzyiBj@Iy@LohX32JXSnnrtUAzrIyM54Oo/Qq7cx1WGuUGg8its0UPFk7ogFYRSb4aKeH@LvmXLt2oMCTZkIrmLDFouSK@4oYSQUxQLAYl5xs3gvcWMjZglGcVgg7tsQrTyIL22ItTyItzbEzTyIr38qIMGgvLqqJ2/TWbt9W7SZU/OZU/wvTPFaTcPe16rQSWHCZxfXp7Eg2REcCnrVhTmofWYTcrtldy5sWRr1139JuG1cqlSNK5GGX9DsCzD/8h8W78kN3RVG6d9JD60NCsyJevISE2bcFz5SJK6bpGxJs9j@6gJsxaKexfyyf5hQxJdLiObrv07B5JPNz/S8O2b89AvXtaRsK7FqyCL474sI3PdB0JHyen2xt1Ex4EX22j2DRfcgQSAgN22QtSxIXpXvLqyyaeNr5VbZskGaV6ny679RdarzKwfiTwwE77VqMHNB/2dqobFqPhXKA40EEjY1z5NX36XgR@k22MXywJ8n2LnI4cXt/uXvZtudlMyF/0e5xMkFbPrS05478P/pqjhuLsXxI0FRqy0dt5JArK4uhfj6F0k7ZHizy@yiRfLLf3J56eby0v8gKZ0c85v64BauQSPLboFGPSidyUUPDDaZPxoAk5LTGusYNWvOWnI4i5XBWLoDLZOtLM7S2Ws6e56bfdNkZ5CfC4OluST412PG6L5EGGTWKPnNVr7CcOnMTdfm2irSIZvbFWZdGZjT2BgeR5niWEzPZkbguJESMhZRq9yKYvbOC8wFt3OFn8ibeMcjDwFao3BUVxFAgrCxcxK@DnBQTRpwc1F/HS2Thr4Ja80IWI5zIb4@gEIFNVU5FRHdb5HbAej1etOT6RBvaK6Sq@AYqdGAyzgWBEfTk0jhxIn7cBoMqQcuOLWERSQxb0yt5FOYWOkrVZ@pOq/axSobDdEbr7MbOk7itvUmwTjmytxFWQAun5hBpSqC@xasZuFhoH7GiMQVrav68yQY@WULHlFcg6qVwH4RVl0p1WbKyI6JhaMKDZBn05MUhjM146wb40pOPYLFT7lZXcPI@aAbZ@IjQoixjggiZ035oGPXMkCiLIgmaSxr1VsVGSVG9JzI8yQNcau61kRFY2SxiyL2DG00y70Buy1io1bGwdgMNM8CcYQJejWum03qHWWYdrnFv/vTn/6HYuWs0dBpHFMnGHkkM3BEkgQrPvfD5/rbQg/5RNkqZnD/xwS3oO77veDEQ4Sa2EJNxLUEM00gMJ8RocFpVTik/SY8Klu@YHSFIKxG48H2trP/@d7uF7CGkksEpoJMcRDBPae4KsPOJVP5SjEYIIoSFmGeqooBpBuxCGV6BTDTY3avMyhbGlg0Wr/3z3i0@C4/hKa7rMsMQmQXxakP7gmhW2ujNROhKRjz8Hv/VDCHY9GezUccjouKMOnn2Cfi11eR5YV@CUR@fX/7R/@Sq1MWJcTz4V7lxK56GdPPuQfqQpZpttY6XNqrVDU8CEsRXzpEv//njCySIN16Iyxcs3dFgyS/23/ybx3GgccHmj2rpJPCs3opop8JIvN6wCO3FF/tUnx/IPj6Ab8C2Ii683QXn9I5WZ/AaKhsJTcuGb6//SPVYoIPYryZXFDHjVRzC7mT8d/smeWyajqWza@Ff@kM/7GNVJm5LsMoB1Uunp/@TbJM7W6K62Sh72vW6sw0LbfDP/0fedTHOua0euABXNDaU5W7Vpa0@V//G4N/Vrg2u4Rg/u5Pf/6LpI@zpT2bLe3Pz5PVNFvsxWxZ269ltqQf4Mgors6WTsVfp6tJrdyZa30uQ/BXy8Z9lh7s2bIlT6RvFv3skmW/DMnPNBKz4GeXLvlluP5A48pd7NluLVnus6XLXGNfstAz@G8saSYtxv9qL8bZRTO/dM0vJ4t/z8jB8MF4dGFaGg3F4TSZtb3vtPhfeObFv5vZ1ti7H67aEsbFJY6K0EFqStEeoGb37ZV/lo0pfy58TZLaUs4WdI@sWlqqFhJNvGGUU5Xrfmt1rWHoSNzLqWXzwyopnDcaI1@M7qfjPqQOfr87Ycljws9/CB6QvzP@Ls8lcdskroi1DbsnOOAmH/ILTrRAPkDHPoe0qAEP0H0SN/jf@6a7tZaksLxxLYtlGApLdI2v0yEKLRVElCSx2jrMFSpETs1dCP/Z7EAiXXVFusJgqT6yH9kk59LN@/d/YXYkM0phGnsG5erlOP9MTQOrGPFbOXvsUDzdctRu6ssIUulUfQQsPbr/i71bZKpbzktaYMsw/@E/NwedH0GXtU/9gckre/xHcEwMzNIT0No/5ScjKFduJFvG0pr/hZ74SHaoZZXjJLtCPUuq@fN/XARp5w@SZLcvF7IUxqUylvP4mfPyxc6es/ty//nLfVzI2I4RjQy@XNATsVv2ZRZg05cEC7Jsm8T8NRFnrTwhr6AarK5VuPv/6ufovqBddYvNojVMF5b741S5li53wRjxVFx5hNT4LJSXSwtqndSteuu662qESIB@PIqxXiOffigwuZgQh8/qbBPyF5NpW@pWFQueK0z9t9kt6zJm@WUCjjpMgNtyMH9u8zvK@M1QBl9ZzfF65@a95gl@6oV2@cmgv2kKSt1s5l/4np6e1gcITzWdBHU/gnuiCI7hGuMjYhZGIV9qwm02EV7QI9kWzgunvTfJr1rPG731IijIfDqDSrS78clc/i0suyMeH51IKI4PvSd2HL7trc6rvSohq3Z7b6qD035bZYhhsFE4kURwPxP9cRLpX8F4YCDCGPfsJqs7fNMLh8ztFrtDOsiKSdXSQw0515/qexyIYYy@RJ4r76cOM81lUaRw8GjAOfSTuCptXRzMDuaHqeIzUzylzRJJRMwLkYpCMPJFj4PDBswkf5ZUqqs9mCln8caEDK8PUArRkEAz1zApi3DkzEQpfhMvVEgD5DyVBsufnsul9XjLF82jqwmDaGJMA@6XGwdfvjp4dTiK/NMbh6uNoyocHQG6q8waeUzZZ4/8xugP3w7HYZRKGvlRLAouTZ3UO1bUILQiii9qrDIaN9Qso3ATJIMG7UCXM7FFP4jLgTJTZW2cY37eLh4UkzGWhh2oxmCkA61koNLw8GSZ2tuIDi1ESDdd0pH48nShil9M4E9Lw9ZozOEAZjSHGSECNaSXioph6pynW4XXMkmgYRcfuJmu6HyaioNMltXNczX/dvOvv3fzB7Qu8lvPBCubYkZpbObThuur5SIeMTdda16pBY0b3hAu/4o7I3ZPoxUHK@0bDW2aIvWgCyrorDX5PeV4Ql5SR0oLBXXNIfs6c1eWpawLPaRG0yR5hed8TQiqvGwgEkEkp5ivis3sYiTpysbBz2J5xU6tRs64kTMpItCzJY08VMUQyNN223AIp20enUeEryUavSwWOpH3FvGpxBXRjYapM9lzmAq0hSFNKOisd5hb@4HVaGvTyiAAIS4g6PsDbzqM7xWyG16rZr7MHiVDqfco@VJkIHsFERhvwW1RKisbIlMvFrhKD9jtJf06KBRb1Wa1xf815f9iVSfq/1uLic00ZCud2Kxm/vu1JB5iZPPFolbzFjbkwq9WnPE8Pg5Ha4UVx5zZDp/Z8EcoL6ivI3kfjkbBeOzHHObIOfJHeNxG4NcgxI0FnH8hrg79fuOzf5F7GrkjT7Gd11EHiDoKUX08d4ofbRVp3E/G4SR2vhoGXf0bMcrv3NJf0TyCG6nI95kHiogJUs/c0Pfdn8wfx7sj3Es04DE5DuV3dxh2GyckyvsTduUY0ZoniCCsT6ajBrub8kd9PIuzGYL3hpp2TNVR1/odAuugW@UKKC/y4Z6y@Go2GBTZeYs/7L/wwbjh9sgxkVQe95nv8KLjIra1FecZMWH3xN2K9mFivHTxiPtOST3G1YYSz5k1BkpWpC9ovCOWJWtmFKEUrd7r2fVfsc4P0FSqWGG2rFzhEzGME3ityqkKiGJIqgT6iCB9whjjrEh6hBChPixLVCNWHUclcDuST1VpksAVqfM5qBJ7iF5pK1q/TNMqPGPrHtx74q7MbVXMThHATqq1fg@xObgnGFBMk3oabq0jhx1URg4izolvGrsfq65qCQHKhHAgROKxJ/DI0H3NSqS4rKPDA/RX13m4nujCJdqQY7zg/mrkH3GUFOe0G0gomH4QMQBKNo6@CsZqiKopUu1Oj4jV5rXAkVWCKJr6t@@u3@IGcVwjDdoPeynQtQZhhmvZBjfuOD4Zml5sxMfO0H/rD8X/mzSbY7/IomQ6K6vtE9fNdypMOjSUqZ7SKJQ3qpK2vfPZkwf7O9tVp9a6DXAxUDWwZWtwJXuV89mAQ5ERisjyrXfv3BIiL0fV0lajVFFN37KHfdVusEZAe9YEcty4XHK5mLqZE8QkMvWxV1VNvEUT2w262lhuaMp0gqgFRT24euWvrBRB0qhrBSSY2hypTCU5NOiLNp4FoKV7BY2A2t06EMIQSogpt3j/eq1m1tQ9/lWjjbVW2xQ78@IjksPfOKW96Si125Z47XhOiTY5eMuTre16ifeFerHtHLulj6NSG9y54ZzelqeVMx3ibzRAK8oycPvhw7mev/JUa63QgFQOWoeVikoo/e//RWLfeWIWMCzHlTPw11@52iVsXTb1HfGgWS7JbTAV@6oe@7P4EW@usRu3TYFu2J/XOSRp/xGdvf3yV3Yd43LljLWbe657s3JGVU7GsEMZ02bo7xPGShtpg1RaInK8ejWCW9wbkL9@8PTJ5zTle/AvFcUHXx7e@KhRLZXoiGcNJBeRPpzt3afPcZMwqdT5RuGzSXiixmXimUrqeNiH5TC3vlpE1xpYhbRzHvmx6n30cL7vHT3zTkhi9mgI0hc4nq31gzD30OW3x8gtpie3WDk7chnqeOIP2sIJnUfu2/JRpR3TP8d2FbepCndtjbHHVMiFA4HMqAcjOq0/33/6xC3d9xxgdXNWRWm1a4iDCIUJpowkFmhTpINwuqCqWOw2mWDoz2qpuJnuy/2Gt1lqn58vbc@T0OuLx69SQsD98rSqKG7iLk5pe5JQwXzsu0iQo@17O/vFKpWF7ItEjnE0501LnBG7ug4hN@wUfATOXwDGdW998gmnocg0ct21ZrMC9ZBzwsY@IAitLKxJ@3ziuf2yGUhvHNT56tyfSV3MnKzV1xreKDoldrTRutPcuNn8NJzg3aDvR71PItpCXA8hZYN4/gkM@Vmd7CgcDj4ZBEM8WF2/dWN9N3j493@w8eLOdrnX/R3iIYuvoxAP@JOx3YCJd6q0/2iPnfSEurgRI8LZ8xpj703YuNVv9tab6627ff/ubX@9eXO9d9u/udHd2NjoDW6td/sbd727t3vdBtxGc5H6CSsPFoX8Ue3gatUuY8zW15obg0Grdedu//bGYGOtefPmre767X7z1q3Besu7efNOf229u9G9mGtL2lOgDVbvuzg7sjvwx8uZu8LC3q5KV3Dz9kXgT/q2v@eq4/W9sQ5Rq4jc2AnqaGpeHPlzYsl6jWDWYByd8u@Ex6POo3DoHQVh4NE5MeRHfVYLxs85/4SjpqNJeBo5iLLHGX0LqD9PfideouRb8YT4tA26/LESoPWt0PwBeJRys8oSEeRfR91eaKNxPw1563YCmrgCS96IWpWF6w9T9mYrr7AKEml0IzhobNbrFvrksTa7paSVBeheBGC1sevUHK@yxDdiqsUbNDB8Y5BqsW6MZfKy2AmOH72sQRwBjuTKHP9iB/1Ztc@3hxIoe9s/mvh@VObk6oYRkZf4rLy4OIKCZ7ot937EuPVnuHrEj/nyKVy7@3/biFCLfrtD0rqZR9UXEqx09rq@91sgZLbYs0tiJzg4lA8aI3YtCYepVXDLJEWFk@AoGHnDRUzzyxYNe0Ui7gXPG2XYknbmFWi9l5xSJWu/t2Q9@Zc5Us3t0we0FddCeY81VqEFb6x2x6pO70rLfm3tA6c0l35TD0W@@BpVEdRF9I@mY1xs@P1ipvWKuSjBkqh0hTG@cIe8siGbV6lc6jdWZtSdra7d6PPQunP8nKcAEHncl0hPNnWlB02ArrMPIdhlmG9D5NnxnLkdrEu3M794RJaNnvYQax@NZur7sjngaH8LX7D6uDQkzH3Am0jbpB90aAw6y7cYhVO2mQ7vLB1sLZ25/LRQ5QyZGbH3Hy0mStWPzOD0aRTRhj6No27A4gC3c3bG1A1qkpW6X1eRm8cDyEXlir6@MtsU5Y34LmxWnXPIg1YNImlf4q3L@2048mtJLDF5xk0mLENTKu48DHVSdjpGdNfD00b0wVgHVmfr4M5c1DFRHqpg7CnzgvIqicNyd2aihqq7S6s6p7uJXJvdjo4va/mHtbfNodFVPFB2/Cl@X5tVNLiCy7pj@svO6rD2YVKBKpm2vk8Rd4dXPtG3Q/LNUIJSMl/KJmo0QfSjrJZGpaAs1zge06oqQbz4zTtNM6IoMuvP2WBMDamsoIpT25QiCYHIN4ZaLS9hwtk1VeLRicq7LcLg0iFv006qaWoGCNRtYVFRIj@lWPp@i/kYRh0h9rYF0cyD2LBx1HKREBuRD5M0hFiVfJAEC51cuW2xIO7m9yeBIDbdhF7nMabBV/OQHkMzVzKA9JNba/aCg5ZTbSpK5cxbtyupTEPHnLvRtHKb2VwaH9PCg1orm7veTOWmqqVBSWWmSoJ/tGtNZdJQVOwGm7X@zf6wa3JbT0LzyPct0SfFNqhYQBDdnVPIkCTyOvc5KI9mGjQ@OzKQFgURhIzjc1maHBdrbThQ1lgvsR7LN@ys7SYDDdH3iggspn2dl0U2ZZ64iAMbvfo/';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`《`《\》9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0  0
0  0

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]>84576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t};prescata, 8 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>          K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@   A=AgRA;       AC
#   /         
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[x]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s》say 27#》say 167#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint ("65" )#`=>ass#
#9'>+/' 25  pe+--[red[ ]print 221;};]pppppe^ee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*ss<s*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .000946 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 10775 bytes)

### Explanation

I have this thing where I go on Tio, pick a random practical language, click the hello World link, and throw this line of code in at the top: `#1 “”`. So as I was doing that, I stumbled across Nial, which gave me this:

```
#1 ""
write 'Hello, World!';
```

This produced no output, but still had an exit code of 0, which was promising. After some experimentation, I derived was that there was probably some kind of literate syntax, because leaving a blank line between the  `#1 ""` and the write statement produced an output.  I should note that I wasn’t able to find documentation about the `#` token, so this is all guess and check so far.

So after a visual walk through, I saw that we didn’t have a blank until we were deep in the scripting language’s literal string. So I plugged in this answer line prior to any crashes: `write 224;Bye ;`. This line outputs the desired integer, and kills the program so it doesn’t crash on all the later wonkiness.

You may notice that this line is now immediately following the Korean line. I can only assume that these Unicode characters get parsed as non-existent, leaving the program to believe the line is blank.

The spacing in the line allows no new Incident tokens to be formed, which is super helpful, and left exactly one troublesome language to deal with.

### Grass

The word write starts with a `w` which grass cares about almost exclusively. I couldn’t shave any `w`’s from prior to this space because they were also being used by evil. So if I was to put Nial here, the Grass solution had to be re-worked. And I had no idea how to do that.

Fortunately @ØrjanJohansen was able to provide some assistance here, with the [following suggestion](https://tio.run/##bVExcgMhDOx5xXZpcv5FCnfpXGOQz8R3giAg8esvOuzMnBOr0GiFZneFxmxFlqW1QzvcorVmzBe06klz6/Deatu3w2bqAfZK43H8KdVTcEdrmGEAsUfKNLzN8SO8wtWciQtOlV0JkXEkF2cSWPg6z1dIhLMM6z3mmAk2pSk4u84KSlwpQ0E4gYk8@Z0xDTfpHtD3PQvlAvou2W6FxsAceERgdDewmaxRxvcoZaCbQTtNqClRVhtC8LEeJxoqhD4rsVOnKccp8kgexysi07qCrUJKVM6U6UV6t7uXYt0FNNGsS@@wRzkHvmim66re1dSO@pDIVpWQooS@7Eqnf3G2KrUz9@22Z/p7x//1087vdZblBw).

Based on this, I added a `vwWWWwwwww` string at the end of the evil line, just after the jump command, and several `W`s near and in the end of the C/C++ section where grass is interwoven. This caused a few Prelude alignment issues, which were easily fixed by throwing spaces other lines. Now if a `w` is needed within the literal string, one of the `w`’s from the end of the evil section shown below can be cut and moved down to later in the polyglot.

`seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww`

Good Luck

-Chance

Comment: You can also insert more things *before* the `vwWWWwwwww`, as noted in the TIO. In particular, anything matching the regex `(W+w+)*`. Adding `v`s there may require more tweaking (and extra `W`s at the end for each new stack element created).

Answer (score 7):

## 233. [Haskell 1.2 (Gofer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gofer_(programming_language)), 10890 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JArwNFIACUHiQIECAzebjNu90Nzkk@/a9Q7LRBaBAVLNQha4qkECzeWM06xhrVgqHdnasGEnevSPZWsvejViFw47QxmpjI6SvG4r9Da1PDoXD8w/kc05mvfAg2XdGku0QSKCyMk@efJ08ec7JV1t1@n/7twn8sEPLmFwYlstczXFZ19avNDvHnkzYY1V3KsVSLIZQW/bFaKCZrlOLJZjCmKlds32zo3fBj7nWpWbq7zUbwoqMDW3rwlYHzO2rLrzoEIvtaMaHwQeXdazBQDW7DkCWGDtUIbA36lwyte24ttpxdcuEoDJjL01DHbS7KgMIzR7amkvoK4xtaIOhO2nCyypjzy3b0TDFjuY4FkKshSGqAKHauvVs68XnU5jWGftchcwMDW08lbxSYK90ze5OxVAU9uXJ3t60b5F9T7ZMtofFmAoqsZe2oxrqNP4y2xq51r477V9hWxeaqbJibj1XnA5cZU9sdSbKGrM1tdvTDS2nmx0ms75mDDWboQ/rWTa0kqsZ1UK10NoKYuY6GLcaBE6hbXgfptoXDgRaVxo4NWi/oa51Wc@2Bkw1nWtISVkvBPCIdp0ZpZI7VRfFQqhZikr4pRh@KYVfykx51pomgWIFfbcO9qf9V1nx2bTfGuS4c9mbbZtilR1Zw8m07zp7rj@bR3ilAtsdWG/1basLZZ4KCxenVIx2gA60D3Qt9taBrHQ15pj6cKi5PBBaW7MpGCqeGbp5GeP97dC2uqOObl4AnAbJDUcuNakT60C0JhuKXptDB0sQEXAwyMKxNdDCWXSgu0KjOUOto/f0DqcNbexqpgPN7eSYDtVzrRsG62oGRAiwd7LMsdjICXm1DbWf6@RiSFuYChtcGkxnneGQ8SAoBmRpr1BlGlYYew/hRt9h4@GAOfoAgt2O1etpGnuvDfsQPda1Ygw@neFUsfy3FQ1gTM2rGm0IfRqrxsKqhnryaujaVqFubUfUgasPoGZ1N@kwTXV05G8QxdHMLtXq0Od8FtByuMLYlQ59Foo@sgm3o9nUawgv9DBbA5Sq386pa1t3oTaxNrbYoaba7MTWNIm3seZ01CG2cDhJSMzCFFwsSI4adWMjuXuwl4TG5TFy6hAa0y6dfP@LmMpyDbbSqsO3EY/XY7svdtjNyhm6OYcFAhjaKVVijW@Ykz870@A7Vtr5C/s2BlhjUCsGy1tDN6/KQ8ig7EIG8yo60SVfFXNDI5Qw25hqixDJcagutAbwD/ZllkrWGdk2jgVBpaqXUGjDMi@gPqGw9sjE@jDZagGaoGPBIJBl2hXUGjBPaiPrmmr4pK9DoznYJCGmxIcnqlAYoICMRY166TqWMSI4iOm4SMtQKxAVMe732Jesp@oGRoFwRMVzbWvOyHAxzsjsYssPdFPr5piXDeqxNtDxFSSnAlLyANIfhPolZQqAoSEsKioGffydP@heXACerU7HsruCXL9kXatDA6lKmYWhkCHBWqZqULYALoup8@iQwJVq6F3iEKo5EUlQJijVa2tkdJkFCdrXOvTSvgp8WoPO1XE1TuTWyIU8ZtlAveTcROeUCwUfqG1oWEqA0qZiy@zxNrRSR4sliGbkwcjtVZk83GVJJ/86tVlLbS6faZA5KSelV/L5izoQXC5NXvCWvItyvtyKjDKOqzqW3o0NJ27fMotM7rB4p2ENNTOVjOBIZpN2OynlkMulpLre6OR6utlNJTeAFpuQcFKqdxqdU712Xp@KHk4S0FwjGuyuWqojxWPAcqhTXOUHIIrkYDz4UhauUJjltLDKMTgX8saKmfa74h4JEnSQLi0kEOBDOcfQtGGqkFMkZBMIN7fcGDCvpFM4RIFr@nkmmUhmwkUnDFDSSEGxs57oFrItY9jH4RAqxXSGMBLYSLsdFajHwQHBBQEwy9pE1zSKAGchnnitJUEAaAMj9eiIuiTvchhfRkYpMARdKNqTtW6oIwMTgL7sOjPc2LBQsKA84TADrMPERNULaBqIzAuyxQvCUyKfaJEuTWAoiK2tsarc1qETYHcDni5oPlQ2AC8VOQxg450kxHsG6gSwdPiwGnQYpvegLw2APdgT1tGQ5wDz0fiAgomMqP85ICUzq8cKcrFSifaxmS7m2vkt@QfApN/n7@xJWPhwZ0JGw3oglBuqeTFSL4BfWCZEUTsdbegKRgUlcVxgRdPjDXnKYvDMOf3YyuPptGkQ8USLIA1k8rz1xFCoIncRQr4M8gxKjVxzYF3dBrZkTKZTB4CrqcTjbxAkkoE38QVZ8CQAIDJtrHVGLnA1IODrvt7pA81i7kzOF/kgNJ08eIVTB84u9/ykMTNK81Exlsv7XpiNhShkbNFZPDC4IqpmxIMaP@xxN2bVGcxBbPlZhIEg5JvLqzmgvXtwDizTmoMUKtJHiyDREN4OIIkdo0AJA5cndlFn9aVMv4mgzYBrQM8H@uu77tCpwTihu/1ROweUkj@xJ/vugYnEknftie5a3N02rDawZQf6Z95LId8ZtfXxVIHIz2/Dt07sCgSwnsMaMHK/GwHVpZI9Bxgm@W8jcCgoToybUPDfOAASUA4qKtVziBXvAVM5npidVDxClPEsi2PfjUvgwIh@1XyBwls0m2/BazqXCBbOTC6PUHnH7pBDDsmkiB7BKVuxpUjRHpjH2FI8Dj891XA0eJojw8DXkcm5XIrLChK7iS0tAWtLUXL6YGjoHd1t8VD26JGQKdgyqIcoNvVQZpIgzpLQw3PAUABGDD8cOudaxyTspiQoyNJtJGHNti2bp@v2beuakQeCxcKVum0NkLuzVyRwoQQNGrFuonYnxlIaStW5IoQ/ppK8nEzm3lq6mbpJLi8vJ2vJJoyYy8ub4NpA1ya6MuDaJJdMLoTLoYtiZMmFoacUA/3Ok7enHuaxdI7dYYyj/Xt9mFJPa7XSeVY9VcSziE8J6hlGDICW8QF4klKjgU5JijevoaC5di9a@m0c9Y47tj4UlfCFeqXyd1ELJaoGaDjLRsWgjsLL3XUyaNggXYAy0Omn7OTZaeHs/OzmrJs5u01mMbZUVxttKBSklxrkLmxrBGKIdFquycq5JJ2WQPhoN5KFZDqVqsoGJKRK0mdVKaPy2k4lNRgNU2dnSahUUT@nnb5N@MbZoiT5VQX5QIEHZO1UMndThfTb0rmUSUJcKZkF1a2RTELNdLASHCo09qVIBR0cfY9XzHYmE6PubdmX@J0ZTsEvB4prNPrh6P175F0cR9unMGOkcilvKADy@6YHm8PAKeXVC2r3GPLRSBqfWz2uFW3HtDE10@cHe7tHDcLfV51LECbkCwTKg5AM1WF3c8AGjFFXi82DAX4Brk6QBVS4MdWLTofJFiMwucNTD40THbYAGzAZkjgtJhsDnvc94Jvbx1ELy@ASRnXWcQwUgWWbY4PXfJp7dunhS/o1tk@akgliHrQwSHldXyM3LVNGjuQpVVY4ITJDIAT5ocyD47kegUHEPX0MiimMNxNPAEe5EWXwbcsEFVHLvSKeFGfATtHeouXmSuGHXJzJdZygj4C8Dc6hoXaA60bRncXZGSAEPpDPzw@R6jOIp0V00qbvKyMINB3VxPrr6qQtjnSnj9ULEj3yYrsHtYqqIsikGtXaPuuArHkBNa2NdZfrjtDPjjHKU9VJSaitbHFpH5scJVXMlGd7IjHS6oCerYHEiqHcaMF2zSvdtkys5NwuoAaGUMc2mEI@r3qBjLa29os7i@t3HnKosRlvJVS3YazTldtxgNRNy7AuLJYGACTNXI4T9r6JNjrQNVx1CEqQ/p4qaOvCMidTNKhpvtFzteRrfSpC5gk@9xZ4MZtf6ABgQZmP93@wC8KAUikUIP/eW4E@fiFDWKbLiJ4dFgAIy72BdIMt@QNt2J9EbJdIH9x6AfRkabxjcnuSCoIc5Er08PcUNdzJuQ/0cy@o67nmlX2XJHM0oYW120jpIzID7zZQwsSUN/p6VRFBOtPgQfsi4zrLR/iWr7DLvYHlqvkvc8Av8SeGcqqss7iTTy4n87KMv3EKYsUmy3e1qzxyqQDzeFfrzMU91rROHkNxiGGeY271eIELquYMPib9QDH506sDP@Z0@S8yGWT8lDs/bZ5pGGpP@iMtpnX6FoufgaAfLlkcxsU@aKwy1DyIYagd@NHELE7MtUagXHU1Qx/o7j5ZnQ0TNYgcMe8cci0RivbyAMGhroFYzNX@YBRCy3AweJoXHP4IODlhBUU7x6vU1rr5dIDtuWXZoN05TCHNvuhX/UAE5C1n2M25Y0DAY@3SYOt4g@6Lg53d1uHWydNGfuTYeUNvA4/oaq0BqJQGdIcFH8wb2ul2gXZ00xroUCIP5ftL48iyXD6So@n7YZ8ERvRwPNtpPdt/crR19LXIHOJy9MHIUDGPtZUpAB/HMcHciaZjtS0Y6M3RQkwgpRw8OXjmYfni5bP9rdbO7uHBSQjN25Ghq8o4P7y8WFSgLxCEKbkCr/oDoxudkyBlMaLLC2aDmk@dgYbIZBl@ZfTjiaJulMMAFFRxeJRltMWqaG22WVEprK9322q1qq12O@XyWk/tdbvlolKt9KqVYqUAP2ur6xr7QOCyrI3JfgIubptAMw6mAZmnh5IriywVKmpb0eZmigfdkS2tW@1UKxVVa5c7HRVy1VktaeVeobBe1opFrdwu9xRVKRbvzBZPxZO3QD3tgPw0mZshP/SOPHUqFW2tvK6ud9bX19XiWrekFqtrmra61isXCtqqUui1q0q1dGeeQtlAQS94G5BVCHgAGhAoEFhxCh6Rzskz7/RBXukWi8XVTqW3Xip2K4Vyt71eqFS7bWVNba9rhV65pBSVbqeo1Ly4aGUFntUH8kFR1QSp1QuSFQiUYt7QHiY4mrT0JrIF@1spIcMbehPRqEyIgDIGjMQ0NJprhf8q@g9w3jnX8eRrevU9BWCVAHH6OWe3Pc919PQnniNTssCgBdeeF744ksB8oxRuEfk1Tl2HynGjKOR/5fZ6Ee8ieV/KOIAagXeJvPnEdXTKWBR2JmgusI@vTPj4hPdcfDNBc4F9fBWODyfK56ObCpkH6iNbJWQ4sT4X11TAHEAf0xphCk/GB2FVCls0Ey/Smhu8MJKPe51w44x7gIrm34WXB1jk7aAYLbU1GOgBsOcTCgKlD4ZhZTWIXPEjW1NRLT3w9sF5tRaNFig7o1A/8XzCQX4kXoPefH2YJou8Am1rOAl1pZsiL/tAF300RNwl3hdoBhpVHjsSyCmfz8y33vLZnZaYmMeezpnHCcjMzyzQdJ7pOM/Ri3CTmG@xOIvFPbNL1PAWhBSDaSUmX82fD4uHEXFGqZuXFhkafFerkFMqiMVHMbg0ZmP2QCmknwjoTKZmQ7ikMWj36GcOAIpH05ZMCiAzsRDSQChS80f0QIPxvBxETd@R5NtabwT6ar6tm@i@B0xerxJkr93WF4FCTeBCB@85B6zGjkbtCSvmyjnFM1DgVBOMZ9xufbJ/QIBtldTt6HwJi1S@O7JdiCWe//mHXWiE2SbqqxPS2n1Hy9SuiT56C1tMRMUX@pnfuoF8RhVDrvtQdlScolYN3zEfNbW@LPdVe4DKsWhuIFD8AUq4g9Z4zrkJy3vOT6TGqJKj8zLM1AesMweaYKemkHhiZA4xLLVL1cCNFrpGkWxsbN4M2pir7yHRFFjMooTmzPSwYGmF2x@5I/6Lqynua0Z9iN@7umhJyH2gx6htXbujvW31ctS1ZBDHqbSYp9U5sEHBya4p9wz1kjtb6Jxfcl42W7@4ADFLPBeBXfdBASXLQf6aHveRhGOOnKHchnZyoc/QG/WCwR0p2Ab/XQSii4WJvmNxrekG/TygvX26IkoBSZcqGldOyaFK06eq2VDbE7Sn9D@dwDBBkgeB3TQ6mUyhhCOoP00e2HCHw8Xxcdil@Ovr82PzNVu8SubpwHm@VkvmtnYqs1i9dU/DwpilD1RDLnZDzoXM3LOyB645oGRckzuG6gBpuaI5tCtoPvq5i9xxUOqAbmwHrjuIPciOt1pi0cS74FiiQ3csQ3ewVxuLmOf0XGWQJq6ao5@QEV@fV7FdEjGdvuy75vMFq@PirPcCQnsAg@MTzjilH6KcnLWo0jrWNX4XShV960rjv/PHuPdzc/UAjiUbRBJ6Z@5g0u3cR6m4cop@5tfj5dx8uR1jrn@0D3h2qLDe@kC6dnTDctgx/d5VLSBGOw7/nU/R4RrUVVOmqbOwe340kakhywlT@IJ2VY0Ly1itXuRV@FnY@CO7h2OCeD6U@/ncS1Hu516eaGSZinguZPuXefvyvraj@SMb1zeEnHeMwPNYmJi/XVxAUCJw0dL8wu0VqhQzl@fmhUUNYHf61@rEe36HkWVR7Xojy3BCojZIfhhhvQoO1@bi93dJrXx3at2HsacZtGv3FSLUuJeGBgMZ/c40KSsWlE@MoRQKD2dWPWOkjbS5vOqg/VbDlep3KCAPz1RBFGNFmKTRUIYGaR/qvVAdH5RrHMPx7U4Goxo6dPJ7JZ25/G4I4vkQte1DcByiYzbihTkaRho3osCZR3fXXH/o9WyrG8kkhnwqR6reL09FpH1Ho@@dehXXA3ECslEqFApCvglNMkRe7tK3Sn7ctzr/jSRMPkHKESvJHJyBRRmaWr90ZLTtPowbFRcp/wS8vp43dVNzJ/i7qAnmcde2ZRmf0mTAZLs6ymsgheJs3H1NNyMLiYVyLDBzOGgkafcWGTj4ACQUUag91LHvav2wBfpBzSrjOgLolRdTr3ebfEL27PtSgWGd7Eh8cYmxWNAUxhMlV82t3dkDufhqtTVD5Y/xavkufOu50p34fBFFyMU04YiTlHxaMpjmTkzxqeEEKkvvglLT1wYavd6hDajdtyPHeywEGlv4nROco0ngRfGGOjAGE38jU6Ah0cm1TFDDXNW@0FCPMXCpgvBdxIy9SYe5lbs/UC80vlvtLm4ZWDVwVTXX/gLnfPtGjS/I60A0vh7nblKAznSpTRzvORfh80kH2nM0uN8qN9XvO7SG676OnsvPnWu5RzY0@1bf7Gt9vlbKf1vUPYAiXb7P8K5CQP7FOixGPCq8litcu4ZlGA@pXeSRnGNaVm9uvnZxC1gXon4S3onahgDxuNfiB@M7VRIN9Iv6Tl8bwTDlWK411GR6WwRqoIGI/y7ipN7813e1PN1pFYAa8Z7fFf@9@uiFarnDIT1aQ2Pk0A9FlWnn3rym3KNkHkIVusvXg3Ha1S6sdqev35eltqa6pn6Z96xA/PVObXYYqgWdyTvonTN0qDx7kkNqaITDj/Gxv6hJQzM8c0u/PbLtyf0cIrqsxbfZ8qkGdCxKX0ydzgkmeQAXPHoL@@6Y7xAzrQvJi8RuFLFlrQAii7LQhhRZ@yrYGE35LZCIpspNmQlNs32K8VOsQiEzoB6y0YJ/hGois/FzhymzP7pwZpkct8p3QbjCn7mtvXWBu3Md5loWcwzrOmSkhrFHNcVj7lDsT0DeNW9SuXPiJJcX056yNlpoCzP0ocN/mdwrzsUyO40@CzWZrwuLpuhqPT63ga77xLmBZeMmKpAb5I6tOR20jyPL5UISZy@mdQGsVzZYAOzBzi3C7Mz9/JYOD2vyVy@0CxUXtz7TcZ2rMYcIAPP0JP5DEH9/pDr690eWq83FOT2Z/xCUz9ULvfM00goeQq92xUpI/ohQO3rNNsR1X3doL4vnmN9DOJnRxPwcjWzKBO/vqb7bVBIShsTSdybvM2@JvO/ASQAMV@emFRU1xZz8Qqamu2ReFc@55Zy/8OEuO8P1aDAcOeIxP3VagxS2Mw8uyd@51oHjye@AwbK@arjzbdEh8yoIUWLUC5yLROsf6IZ1wX5QLTCQuWAkQkl7AWE9gTH4UHWhB5hziJXSf@BkJ1ovZJsX7h0QglZism7q7t2WGtdVQfnxnlggLl/hzsv8M/zNPf5UDPLJ/Fp5dufQDMP3pGOAOnMf1OHX90Bo2/fLP/dM0tRwYLTMkSvjfvW7BonVOweJGhtXV0NUwFLf333@UvKI4aLf4WuK75MhNVDkRo4xCVwL1wjMoTHdBGFrMZudjeFpBDtaTx0Z7hGtgn1AvK0hbhIjrr5jzdNcDicwyHyS@gPjxGiwo3Vw5vBBeXhhPQdhDEauIfDVwZGGM/5TrGRxZIz6zOqoBtRZ90HJHRP6OcNCoDirQ60NbW8ErvnS1iLkO6qrLpCQyBBI2p3vupeWdKOt2W/RzBd2L1JaZzP1VBuTmrGYoLjsI7udDhep0fQW6UchzbvGjocW3zx@B0343AbGCPp5@Nx5DpeLR8a8uarXbDkPrvi6Ea3Ldyw68wj6SGtbxv3sxtT5QgHV1jUn/0w3R2PyYzKIbPOVGb5uupBbQxOG04cOeK2D7uwvp8Y1Z3xtthPoBGIVj3mlOjR9P19biSzdfvjioL5qdyycBxOOT5wFC@2Eu1u5CNam82UGbSCfMTA7tTPyjlO4J6vGoD2gn8VaR7StoRlxt2Gbts666nie3BjdPIeeYoMCnWji7313smLrDPjpttgk6@S8020StM2ICuEteGcJ3J8/Qo3KtewcI7hUSs1kJCnGI@G89oUJYB4UnS@CZw/wo0scBoOZS7B6j52espWbca1QU25Zg8VrcXZ@zrHih3bC746HdDjIEY9@uqKeN1aSspxcSZ6ZNVZI@uCaAfLaXHA1AtvT6cHzG1QBM1W@mQzdXonr/GwFp0/nlvRVs2to7KVJkw8w8tr8hAB@/MQJrp/7yz/piuNcLjQo7EAHnQkqBE8zsgZa37re5OmK1GEcUvE4GMQB4rXBDyeQt7cYyH1up89PcbGu2cu9k6o4G0IcnQQvh1wx9nPBGxft8rjDzuWNx3Pj75YSCfuxvEKBlDEamNB1u27fybFjnTbPjexgAbo4T8t0bTS8dbNsn3U1XK9EeyLJ1mxY1iXtk8Cc/OWf8BMxaGek2LHmJU8n4YRSxA2QCh1D0elYI8i1h@S9ZlsCJIWVDML2CGd2GMpf5C/hfkE6qgMoUvYOqqBk@GkV21vHTN5lSTwVCjeW1/VeamXr6PMvTwvnjW/YIK/95x/mpRtRcfHP5PVVJ55lHkj9FgkrHFyB4CA0yeIr4zhP0N82qgvZ4Zq3B1SRyokMd456NGZZQ9Fr6LAhOlvHp0axZz2Fbmpn78SKAZ1TRASrXdOJFbQ/yUTJAQ8AMh3oYPAqEWre6xorqRGfbJCPXVaBBPHUDxVc/GQj2kiJpy9glJUx@8D6SGQw/iiVArzxijTwwI9B44m3kLUUXmCc39HaI1ppd1XMFUsNKs5Kq7HRJBcMbRYevHP6@mxcLMhn47Xd87zjVerZ2fizQvErqHXLhliP8tjzdl/s3KzkmoUPHxx1wuLx22SdL4gGNrFyc7h/uHt8snXy8hha4dZjP3t8y4jHa5CKaE9a3zLoSCOoFxzYPoH/@G94wECKrahsA8/bk6RYePcQgYq6jsvxFe4MsaZI7Huiz4vvaKHwWQDB03o68yhqH4Z4bEMgNqw1LPxoiAczMRFXHC5DVKYjj8cO5FcMLjufw0upquKsAZUlQ2U9sKrY4sJucr@H1Ni9WO6uts25IFhjfnqnfjgv4twquP21lHsIA@WvXm6O5e5yE8wd5QZQ39eLs7e1/@zl0W40GtAYPYnrNtYrYtscZ87Y0/gSBe80HdqtLiLiRE0jzuIUgb@KwWyE@1fbmnutQbEEc@wMeGSiUMp/PBYQJtRMA0@kPK/zukilKAcog9SxWFO7@nr6OJRFb4wOobvhRfSZwF7cR@1lPBcXmBN0tGAOP14xEKuoLq/rHRITF/w66YTFn6zX47BoOEaPHN7nFgxV/qjjMPgPjUqeq3jOxkwMZ8o5k1kRvoZmXkCBPVipzscotsIrIr7C8x7384vH2kGeum9VMp3SQmix/wxGaUMd4hlaAvqF5Wo19m5k0Y57j5n48sU1GuZUfoIjNW1HxdLQTn4QWEHz8MYtwre/d9xA6YyLZsTfwzQ3MnGgAqDQeYq7uLUPiI1vD@Qns/Eqt8QhYN5QSXqIIw798aUEh13pjg4SNDVCD2UcAzgllkYUHM8jpbMW2JbhgEzSheEbJBQXh1oQTnK0MYfvzpFNFk8ATeZ8kTHL4jGEdRqzh0LBUHoNOkLnDY@8QnCE2QnhTG4syzLU3AUoTmKTTw2P46R5kRpz7REuvmkmZ6J4WaiRS@67AyMEOOd4vDMt//F3/oAfiXfmgvsnwj0uPIG33xJvPXD/theiKPD2z/23Irz9lL@9zmOTzZ4DJpIXuv3CXUxAl4/jM2VCnuAdQUpl8VsbW/rL/UPmgCzL23IA@lDQTMhhkOZAhwX6GwBRXFEbIzhPIWjCAE/q9EsgEaAroA8Ub1CiofQ0@zyFp0HV8nnMOBpXc7QAShvzCUo6HOrdCA9FBCEsv1pZLSt5yKR85SGkkzIucCsGRyhJNeCJsSt92HgDuuPGxgaLOx3V0BqrdU4b@RX1dSn@xs/oCsDGuKJwyiAORAliQFhTREutqBlFwqg4kCWVJPK0rsVJDaTBFDkAREJv09tbD@KmJaoK6NjUxi5JTBNPAQKGbdLmUY0fjekhkgERx41H9013x2CPBZoCQh00F26G@CsEO0awWnwesZ6@ZmfumXkujnBkQHi/mEO6Jrj/2ZxzHTll4dkhswcKpqaPA8TSsMfHpoX2lD3ILUsV88VSXlmVQhQaF6ggv9jVPwBK6NzALDqa/tYaOlvbu/tfHBwezxyMR5DJabAkSzY3MmdyLnt67juSfr6jlfpkL3/8/MmeV5XhXAU2DYQIFqBNZ3NeatM5XZD6K76dZTZtCphJSCk8FDGt7JD3aOHmLPYgNB8C3Oar6WdSTUk3t6fnG80zMzGT/Id5h4UmcmkkLnCdOXRUaHI6m5hF/xjxEzxG3Ml52zQV3KOJO3hc6zLYQSo8QgEc3MMCHCCWy3tQcyjWy8ABt88Eh0gU@TnmDrE@bsOhIxz9HIUgT7wTz7FrBSePiSO3@qrTN/R2DMbuLh5Dx4/q8M6i8A/5yDlDQ3dTUoysHw2UgICJpcS55@PaOEezMSk6MJRwZdldp3h5@KQYdALAlzwcOX12aA1ZYHra0TzXEQgibGfE7fYa@2I0ALgePY40ZLEaiCYyRIaKSvpZ5Qo19CxxiNc4gwelQXqneJSXKHhu0K2kxlKur427@gUw8JSUhZ7@mQISlb9tFgtNB3uZSeBxvIY/x10M4Sr9pLPcxgFy9VTN6WZXG6fwWJTaOYim6J@8fnWVlOIzNEAHym17p2NNnSzndUTVFT0iOJVtqrOtr/udLHr03/o6Hi2DO4ChWSDFY9d@Bk4Yn1K9gTpkqREdeeiwHKPX1FnKzDquLTG5yU9IMFkmQwo1PCgABGYE7ZGLCIel8ITgVL4BrYO@jtnFx3t9yE6VXO4c3JSIxFbQmLYNQzmaoaQYKEgQpUZoG9i2rIY54tSb45QHcTA8Rqc/MTz3b04wndSHU1vQT6EuqNSs@Sh0ak7QA3mtrq/XRGtEWc06A7KY5fK5PKCdw0I8ARXqV2zohFrDk6wBatvWujqwhcff00xTgwoCmhmoMAarIyAyW8p6Fx1kg5OPKYUEz@JTsUMUMho9EXk3eWPgjNFKvk52mfotjKlvznBQ7YlhdZL/r/O5fP0mtWI0JnkQdKRmaqXfUDKldCazYqZTKyYO9Y8eoTnndgUkiVYOtKMxAMkrhlQHegbJo7Fi1lfUjdRKt1FMUwx4Bf3sBiJ84@RzNyvqbX7lEYzUWfCxeedNrTh0qF4hl1NuIX/YQ1byWaCZGzz9jK48wORX9EwG85BbaWEGvsmfHWeIZ58d58lyVBeCaP5iILrbFFf1W2LmjgdegcJbNDQw9iIydrFat@UBB@chl@aFLZA9eMLfww0QjFZgaU5Y8o9HQx7OWAS/S9JJS/wIQ36qIVTgOAWViK9ZVZKAmfzt3yaUVRZPrWyulqxMslKow49Sr7AK@2zlrFhOsMRj0NTz6bgdvznbka@Y1iuuvpNP1V7u3fnh5eHhV9JZiiUT2wev40oZQNfYOn0f@lljxQUf9mmfRCKdjyXyaeXRWj7/5s0bEHfhc9rMNcNQuXPpVE6en6bW4KW5tpbOrlbT2cfJFuZEShWL0jFjup5nZ/rQ6Xbha/XprpFUgn/Y5iamBQ74Z8JvMO5xvyAzHET4enG9oPvgrtRKgp2tqWo6Uy4@Nuu5YqH4l3@2fJu9OWxt/OVvDPLaMj4O8PGT2@foPlYqny0vf/bkSbmchcrj7sMfHH69tbVV3slWDk8rm2W5sLzxF/9xeblY3Cjml88dRzlPnl5@FS8WyvHcX/5R8vDw@y3HwfbDT4kp4MTfKnwVVqmwS/YePpc9hv/kft8NuVV0t3vvcYAEYblBzCaZrJSSx6@TWNz3CUVREhP6a1E1LDOlubn2X3528C7hJprF/Csbnm7iXWK1muBOcMBbyXu7SjQTGwi2epuY5BuNBjjX/su/g/jNLwAPhkw24KdZ8XCtThJNuUFRPiSaq@BQikVI9//84Q9jieYYCaG5v8eKzWKa04pSfaQ88tvoLKFUywePwdv7kPfY@5CiqyjFM689Q82NTet796Hw0K7MCvn57e5RRoIJaiDHQ@Eg34ld/PzV//5XP/@rn9Hfz@n7H/Baj9Xlx292GNNgBMZPrfbYL12erVXjlgW9vA5vz3z/o5wMn1zLe6/jqyxKlqg2si2eK5@EEyHHVD34v0xUif/@iXCxhDeXKp@y81ATxJvIn7y8PjfZc/4xTfiHr/eKPugBLpMFmfbqNhFUqZ84m/bzGsN/YR4vYJ8CF0t8A5U/nvNhzcCfURF4rsnxPFSyoGxIDpvwWYY/@oeP/4q/y@QjvAlk9rPMvvsnljhNnJ6fPzXxr/0O/569x793Lv6ddPDv6B3@nbzHvyMX/w4d/Hvexr8wLweiBc6QyRyByCiI9iGfl/DN5VrizSfeRCzxa/2wGEvI5xn59vY093qcqdfFP8hRdf8NP9wFOTq/leWN181M5pRydtoUWdyQz5uQTZ5b@nm9AYgzG6cbDWubvrlWEz5ysmwlV63H56@bpxtRHALN48cZ7LKPAU9z5ZyBBN9sstuN2@bt6cbt7cYG/G/Q7614gu/txsw/PYLPApgg/By559lpvnmWP2vyzzm85/JN9Mnlz8DRhGcLAE9PY4kbpJUGOz2nQ4Ua8qmyWjmXGXWINIZ1HMZqSrpYylfGn63uFmOJYjyep6APOCqBbLEeS6CEvs4F9XXyePPx2/8Vv2cfv/038ApZw2uyMBRpiYGEs7JZMApXBeVSuQSHzgogYPYLfaWLHL2gscKkMGGFgaV0waXBXwFceqHHChesYBZMRYFAcLis4KKrB48L@OsBFhv@9EIBkReuGKRi4DhBp5/S80NLOoudsvgbDSSTnJLMFZK51WRSP6@sDt/Fs8nW2WnyvJ7IO2dneS6zsWK5Tqfe3t6yVmv3xU6rlUcyPntuHQT/BweD8Oud/4MD6/mBNbDg/@Dg4Dm0W@ZxRn4Mn0YzsyEem4lmffOsJiM18o6UayXyG5tnzZKM7tUM0FgR/TKf@AkwwrO5fBYDhfbVq@v6q1f4f31Vv66Tw38FR6vuAwgw7gBP7gEIXtXr5EA3fK4IK72h8/rVme/ijvyra/B6xUDE9v/zkbdfw7/@/67/5y9Z6vRcgm5wc7uRoo@Ef5J0c3tzK36bUiolXlIb8Ice8I5Rbm6b6CSgG3CdpqRz6faW@8FvStrgCJuYxkaTIgeA0OcTPNWzJEgZoBSmxGTW2dm4UJDqbfDxzdrqB5oXkeq0YmSljXNZoAgpaYlAKuV6vSzca9V6vSrcyupqvZ72oQrwIpwApDlqp469qZ4YSpgH3sdSBbSX0fnuyZS4DGBzOASlVlkvfPjge7VaXd1utdC/9OHDGXTXJC4YaaxXwKdQ/fAB@nhSAoX3hSWmKtdBfVXyxQB9X3VU17VT7/Vh9iyJqxCds6RER78WCgiM8VllY2O13GyulsG9WpWkenyFrzZJXWTWFel2JR/nxQBVNJkQQUp1TSLf2ySGs8QG22wCuTv4YTe3CaptVq5IqfZEk3wPZX2d@7DyaqqaWRd/jWWJNdNM/J2enpYy5fRa@vH5@fmUoIL8qH6jNpTbxo1aQyPJbb0jjhDHxeTqo0eldaicaqF@Fmu1drZOtlp4BxjO/iJXRk/ibDGc2RvayVOyaFXWz0@xOOdnyWSt/pi3brXCEsm6gJOTwCRZdZ1KnQC1We/hLpIxYZ36phNDpqyVEunYkBbhrBVYF@cxbWb1esvgCS3D2jjl7GiG4R25fm3ZRvda72rLscThs63t3ZNscQOGqeLe1na2ePzySULB10rwTsElfD/a3do5eAkRDp/tbh3vfr7/5e7LQ/B3Ym/fq5qmaiNNu26NRtfv8FRuraUNwTf4tLSO7qhv36pD@rA6Z2nw@fiLH3/8xX/z8Q9/@vEPf/zxD3/@y29//mP4/gl8f8qfP/236xX8/eW3//yPP/6rPwTP/wDffw/fP/vlt7/3Q/6l9z@H738K@f25@Ibg@Jclmmn8AB1Ui9VMGsaM9Po60AL5bsQgqd/65bc/@6Nffvvbvw/ffym@vz/7/Z0/m//9@Y8WfzHez/74bpif/jv4/i8clwf703/F/fA5A/@vONxv//7H3/3f@P9fiD90/uHH3/1z/BEv/93v/8V/@vgb/0exWP2Lf/3xxz/9@KOfffzRb3z80U8@/uifFj/@3r9WCuGfPwaK@5s//QX@/@xP/@bf/wL//@f/8W/@9L//m9/6n8jxB9zxf/3Lf8t///o3fvzXP/oXf/0b3y74/fGdv98@wP/bvwOfh@fzIXgeUq5P9fn2O@XnV6mNIBWgATrKnBVBhHsy0UCxjhVYQfxAh/n5P/v4e78JdPi7AAlv/y28wT9/gaCf0MtXX0XCMqR@y5mvvgJh9iuh13wVBvoJYx/yIG0WHn8AgK8olH@YDwWJ/g8IBWBMQHlgkcQJBBf7ce9ffvsv/gj9/Zjo@5thfAXPNwS7gsAfvCL@BDueX4ww7E@w6378xQ8//tE//fiLP/j4i99Cti2X17NbWVm5x@YHgJUHwCHg6kPgAFBBtQaUz@VYERzLG2ijiimZN2@gEZbB1WAsHauU4C2mNMmtoBsigqqa5qahDBqF4DuOldfhDY1FGRgvMzwoA0FPMnjvbCY2bkAYgeKFtQydzSpq/6gTNgAvRuJxsq0qSOhs/ISwQMxG5oi10o0xj5hBjyZhYJgh9DqKK8V4ptrYgQQb4x2GuBB5JvYGnm8azWpj3ER031AWAEfmCSQJUHgfbmbc/AbeG4QT4GPjnW8gK9VGJtOsgk@DikqpZVuUplKhwlHZM4zKjf6M4YK7zceMfRZXqnGulkNVMgGNv5kAepOsU5sQfpZJi@LQv@ekbxrjQzuNqX64Hw/fRG@KLwAAryzjOi34yjLm5jEEjzmqDCULjwzHADWXEXY934NkiUwsQ@2boRdIH/LwKZ8NPpAiOizOysoKuDaa8VK8dQCKEbMva46r2jiVRHJdjcVX1@Pojete@GK@lUPSn9I7afhV4H93mRawUknq6dhKErXqJPNSkjMlq2wleCG8EtJbmgqQIUD2GYTg9/FjcEMN0TPwiyWCeFxyp1lDELnLTIql6G4WiXR3DQUWFnvuXDyxxiBeZ@PxrLLKZwMkrtvHvrZqtcY3SnktBk96H@G9MOKGEmguvKM2t7GB1d68kbmdAd0gxq3Gmk0x88kU8GH1WPN49wQinRwwpVjIxZpfsXGO7JW3DFodxPSb8lqxXClXiqXV1cpaUSmvrpdXK9UScLjVQqVYVNbL5fXq@tot5fIxMIlsLd2ubDT/ycznv/on8z7zffETaxoNvgBvBWdC42eFeJ3MHlSJK6eFLP4VSyX4hXxllcra@fKycSNj2c9o1dcNzjVD1mI3MlL5EnxYbCnGlsALPvJtDOeCmJi93z@oi5lavGmNz9bGlQqQkRQ7AzLi2ER7NpsgfMv7e7GDgwNad8hnImW9m@vn6Dq07sjWYsUSdaSd/S/3j/cPXuR29o9BIv6aFUtQ3aPRCM3Pwn4eG4Y/dfjGkFIeARd8pHBnZTVwFtB5gptdX0DmodlN9gzXeroWO7H4msInWie2IbZpNmM0ZXYKDXYewxt0TnHxbWwj74fPx7Xd51cub9sWqArfHeaJal7yoB2db9Dzg56qeMqeM9Dd/gKIl8MB7rTS7L8zDLuDNmQQreMc4An82IZlzQNYYy8PF5Tyub99Hqefaf88gB/tf/70JPQ82d3afhpbZU8OXuxMPSoCqMKe7e6d@K9rPNSLWvFRfL377Nn0q3gksIOjzrfMKmvZLLBv@MFnlj70zK289kCU3B13lKzkYfQEdb2hfCNvNKt1d6XHXjaefJN5MRqwcrW0rqxXmrsMSl63QUfTuxcaaLRWH@9dtBOqqx7aK87mKqsCZ3qOq97WFb57Q3diT0GvHOC1MniFlBvDvXtdvMAVrQFtvEl1NGQLPeGBXui09Ys@MNZrywOItVWVwfdTPxA/rFJC9dzp4fI0yG8mxJgDjlOteo8VYjkyVRbXq5XqeqlYzVbXq@WKslqpZJViVlmrrq0DZysoVWW1WllXstXyeqkM7BZCK@trsQSwJL2Xz8MIo8Tj9NTNDh6vvYHnlFu5fjOW4EYYxt6nVBAzJJZQEy3fd8TiGkSM48U8jksLe9N6I14s46p7YFyAVmUdltjb2y7s7cXjT/AFzbLbhXi8iy@VaqGw9iQe1yhkG8aFYjxu8TgQBGAufykUnmzH4yOOALf8x@N9fNldRfk3HtfxZXtrbw/TeYsvRYwPYJc8hL8Y3ssagJn4UiqRAB2Pv/PRAdwWT6hMOd3FF0wTQ/Z4yDaExeOfe/kpFADDEYfjGJ56Zd3aisf3@cvWFoZ8QQWv8Kx@D1@26BOP2/AClBiPX4DjwtY0Mx5vgxPpMR7vgKszUcEPDzTHveGmq8bjE15BWEXx@Jig1c5lHAQ94Y/JPH36VO27Xe2CfyY2f3YgaxCij0e7e@3PP29fXLTtydbu50cY8sUXT9W3k5HdvmiLaO0WfCyIAyGXg8n0B/K432qpxtyQ70GIORXSmrQ0zFtLfQd5Ep8LTGTQ@gJCvoCQeXN0HBt8BgDaxs@TATyfqG0K8T4UQs9xux2vI6G6k6GGxirsOHTNc3agdmyrju/jxnIylcxOTlcL53XyZoOUdFOo32JoL0WXmyEbZNLN5HTcKJyD9L9W9LYGpOJn42JFj2eXB5vAzWrL6qZSLGfGteX0@9RZtiVtFpVqDc9otHpJlpSVzdW11@lRPF7Dn83SWu19qpAsMAY/Wel07XxzrVKLn21uyvFTBV7WMmq@WFtbk@q3UHgXhp/2yNVarRRLXWvqpSRh/lD@oIyiDV664TdZT6h4er2XGmfHDZ4DNpHq44YC3NYdwfhTmEaa6uI2@BHe18MxX0BVjDcLNTQSpuLKejUOGcnnpQ3kRsg/4PlGzAS8ejXliDj5J8dqMr90TKmuSjlcXt6yei26AoW9CUOCABp7hbtAaAeot2KLpHWnFjtBgZXuCmd4xEYbrzmkDdWgMfGzfhg3CChr67FYU4hqh/wegbp4xf3yuT28Vdayc3gPoxsJ4bu5Pa/jCcgBg9z@Qe6l6ag9H8mJNnZzTzVckdXx/Lb5Ls3c7hhv09Yts34jv5Jvads37uvE0wP0LlMbTXCp3RSlzVTpmkrVajYbrcZAGwzdCSgGKIpDCby4OHQ@YRwSd4h4i@RbjSdQ2ELdxNNyNHxdGSfGsWYXDwV40nhyM6rVAPa2rjXottx4Il7vbZqNEZXmULNxP8f@AYzQGm6c6PTfnO0i3DbU682t3LSZWfczse/wyvGX6FN@bjA/IqDVKNzWLxqn6P8BfzbkePwclIMP57Em9KL6JKE2nFGbXxNVaIMisVofg5@yVq73WbvRfj2u240hSMN1A2oqJNIztU7gHwwYFVu5VmMcFLrUOC2WirgaJ1ssrGeLCgyFMEQCNHzX4L0MXwW@EK6g4J8yUnHG4tnCuJBTsoqmZF1r14Q6LtRqWNXQRvQKT1XKFNNGqmsxdUOmJoMeWsccAoPos6EOP6B/1WpHmmrwCKChySn53eZqplyWpPo7yKG9kurmnkib5Xo39YS1JPCAQR2@RbZarvcaqddSPbUsNRztXT3S6Ckp1sSOTsUeLkMFC5XGGQ1OC8urSvZGbsm3huq4K8pasXY6WjmVFShi4cPFRvwHzfg5VP9tjMVYeL4A5IU6@Hl9mUsYgYwQ@A1RKjQ0aCxlvVgXILGhYCxQiSm8uJSv@Eslk2vFZFJK1gFqGbyJQUk3xEWSwNuSj5TNOMgo8Vp8vQjhAT@ayQGfNVpVYonbWFd3hqy8HkvcxG5vbjfCq8y@xyYTNSN7r48Yu8iAsp@nKdBcK8GWySXnmmTp2GpsXRxt1QX01jZXz/KhxRXsTOyNlPPLnzrvmtlovubPM1wxAKmCfNq2jFN2LiaaiyUoczf0DuVzbmK8UvlMen4j08yfxeJx7Kli9ixVrUhCk/wmQQcis@0b717s2nNUQ1lKrfE@eHouffNCN26qJbnJFz6yxDcZqBJcZNTMf5NIAS@/paoWS3xiCdPyVvuAuugCawOmX6nE0Y6gseHx@uu119XXz18evDzYY48LtWqtGpb4zx5ns0pSSW6wxyBs6ke7kNcPzKoo35hf0IKmRD1RGyZL5WQpEq2RGDfKfhmVZlNWNopsE4iT1YDF9JRVufChySmtSQGrRQj5@Ju/Xx5vVOG9CLJcDWqxkik2m0q6yKTEx2//De5bLq55LmV1LXGe4EmU1yRw0yxXUUk088JbWVOkhCPzN0i9knA@JIqFamL7QExexlehMhLriVii@vzNB8Y2QFtrdi8u9CK58vmIBrRSA70H/tk3aFL5Rl5@A0zBcVbyuNhmHYE9e0C62WymaQ1OspnBPVzFChmgT2/r51yzRyUgbdKf5qTxT3vte6QdB969N3hNb2is0lQYaA35/Mff/L1icfX//o@/cyZ9aH1ofR@44/r6@qpSTPzt7CefXoqx9NIWS/IjAvnAiycF@/vbkpH7S9GolV6Sd44Ptr@3e4Ijr2biARls@@BFDoOOh1on2KDYMTTVNiZ8X2BvglA4YJ9sHzLLZi93DinOK9qaSr5kmhKprOx3a@KisuwVU3IlnMmt5AvlvFJhIGcV1mrFVaYCm3LwKArhWsGojIq1bQ0nXONLbUsUeWkLYTDsmQ6Kt6PV2OeHzygGsYH00s7u8wN28OLZ1znPl/ufPN0/ZscHeyevto52oRzPd49ZfOuY7R/H2av9k6cHL0/Y1ouvGQQfbb042d89RgT5GLI4lEZ5hfnqF9twJk4eRVWHdLCIt2N1LjU36q/aQzWPx2FHvU28SEvDe2ei/iNTBwUvrN4dby1xaY8herXbtWO4J1bvsCVU6pbSICjgltx@wVljldFX7wt2ZZl1yi@Sa6xTeGGWNtaYURB/zCgPSkdseXn5zIz740O4GL52GfbC7R/gF@Rp/we7S6nVMkuDNlksS0HIi4PDpYL3tvTq6GRJ8cOOdpaK/sv@3lLJf9mFt7L/tvdqZ6nivz3Z@t7SahDtxfbSmv@2s7u9VPXfgEiX1gOcL3aWlELMq6wrkOWW6CLb1N7@s12WBiCpHglFyyA6pryhIlIgf/EDSrDKWTp93beypKi0J1PQXe0@aA88ArWEEuAp1ut5lqWtIfyAbAnAEC3maw6qfdHJCqx4YhwMHrGb2BIWaAkLBPBLuDUe4dhygxUlBsFLPa4GpfhpoVkWf@nQBtjPHLaBQn0TiCFLR9DRRmiIoYlruGNLtwJlqkfW0x4tsCdQBXIat@MgPjUa7MXLZ894YkMSXFNxgmRcip2D0xoCNigi/GLRwZc3Dm8WagusqyUhdOBV4bHbSGvGplsTqwLKubTUAQTR2r1SjSxDoSuLSx0QL77wjTEADMHgLoCLbxtNpTpY1gvN7VCGJKzM3YM9XkJcLNFg0VaWGCZKNUXBfMvNhw/Meztzo6929NVMctwCOc8Wx8dz2kBYCf2WvP26BEFnE1DMJaSYTAZiQ3EoLFSuJah0@PKjDLxcNiGhQpI9ekT52IC39SQlgfEylCKTEQQRiAqj6kNkftaWKbvSUj5NO8BwbRKdaIzjCD@Juj3xj2EBzjqd0alW9Xuh35xLJui79SmGLIJ6XWxrcJeKLXhH9giUnGVt6CZZ5gUqqxiIWl@WaVnWA@8pntrSTaBczQ54okcK0Bmp9V/s8BbiZw6RP/egEgPfq1GDAbN4hN2XCH1pqW2D/l/3oIAfEhTQLRJNCiuCw90d72iHoqV5f0GyxNgPibm/V/PoiMcGchCURtWKx0RwWhHFJc9mADSDXyDD/tsA9JwkObJMRkD4VCbAdqNwsszhbj26vKcQu9OlWP7kUiBbXliK3QcW41crBQxrAYlAKYDFpwBvBqDpJ9qaxXkoYCwkFFSa74YCBtCAlqCPRxA8ID4MuUF8@dPjwyBdm@7K0G@hBTlX4FGir53oazf6it0XfFS2scGKZVBl2uhSVsGFxwWwKji6nFdGI/air2QUajDNi9PzOTBPAWgOWSUHQwKcZcbIQXIOXrGjDvDStwbb2mvtv9g9iYYivpzTEhnvu5ZpUBpSFExkCMOdFL5Ifo5SPawELm@mDnkaWarP1vHJ0e7W8yzkT2IbQQ@YlgHgR/SESAluvRTA19Q6MB53syx1vMXSEnuEOcsyYUvAlwcnYViOBqgWptgdDYuUVIGD@O/RnpTAHhmbk1Q8xVIS@3B2BkNqYY0pg@GH0qBkrpW6bFJaQ2GX4/FlEMHlPQbzgndNLmwgZJeflVqbm9jbQoGV7RJztT5I3OOCPYufynWLYxsNi97@7KFFSplTZ3hMIvIWcQQMjItR0eZuKZLGRqQD9MVuDH44nJMdMUPyOZInhXoCFs9LV/vUvNwn0UbzIvO8bFCis3kQ2mvsJGwvxslBcebFqG3oqIfSxcpsH63mE@8IpCwbWNBoOro61pCeaG0SlnF4cywDfunMLpy7pcOptfHQsHQ8XQ5PusH5dTs4RTYXOzDZAPRcshtzK7aOB8SJXeN0OA4/h492rcaWOp3Ildqhm7bfgJY0NC9koO6efsFkudMz1AsHHEaXXG9ix/4JIZiCoatQg5SE8qylKoWK0Lfp0F3MHF5Wffjic4YHl6Ju7xmRVEN3J7Q@F4UsWqOr4SG/jn6lAdvBs5S0bi7G1dgHqXZhPzRLRf1o5@6Uwqs6jmZPabVDHtEjn3z6Ma59fpzOC7rBfbgt1W7rLl4Y0eLm4hZP0RPkh1GFitZrCKrDNRqc7GjPO3cO1DG@TcXCGiPLWDD9iUoCpKgONE@FSqeHhJKEScZfQpjTw8W49cHFrwt1BHdX1yJ4LairEdQV9bIZRvSZQ5qbDwR8hzjQ7lf7Jy1x4BbXmyITUAvUyFAt1723YZ2XIJR/kfNZXRPZJmQfT@3gB2dCUa8sTstxUuZQ54PWhv@QCkk3I2HWEduQhtjT8jlXiwqkj3gV7sd5xCnhUShXj4IKXRKjhE8DD4zHtU4OMlteRNyzNY0ASEX1zOFTGsyvmfYWtEzbUM1LdNW5/s/Sjt0JNRYdJRQqB@qBflmEUsinHqHcENXX7YOMxm2/WQhAaPleM780sTuTERHj8Bb2k0aRHNMQx6AM8ITWTioITntyBC@b5KXE4aeSOgCubfXQXGDZE54QHoOQqtcBBIUP4gma6angoVI3gtpAdCSphHIBdFv3vHBxmBbkM8vuzi1PapnIgcSa@VnlEg5CnfrZOudJLeaFUN9SuDCRqEHleHIROGFod0ESN7SeoDgYxohGuMo9UytcfPWpiPF6Oi2cwz/bDL/UuDUCO5SGJiBkIRJ2Yzw8YSpzfqYRtOl3HUwqID1qKDRLYRPqRItMB4kB/ZmeyUTaKYT8VMd6U1iGajs1JxTYkF8iUfWi7gmGBH1oDW5fYD0ulvK6jk1VEWgQaKDxcg2vPjUeetPcQBL@lTVI4JwyeV8WFVr33r1O6LspJKgUn6vezhoIaY5fc23reqiPNSMFDLOFB4kNGXgJOWw45A6C8GUy8MbGprwLfrW8nIJYpwSXr56zRyylbGyk1uQUeX1WlSS/M4roxVD0UGRg0s0mSxXTqZIXuYyRAWUpiqA8H0GRIyinU4qHoCgQKBXAwEUMQvIZqGREtVHE1RBiH@95FAaPI5uTerqYUc43NqqouIY8pyIX52c9XcoUITJHvZSJhnC0PCDkfx4tESAvFUPjSAhFOVMCFDzpTDQgSHUqwE80nGb5fO7g9GsTXjzjszf4UHQ8FVmzT6tYXqRUbmkbMnAPXVt44smUQzqfMvDjJJ1GMgcZgbokpNbXcCYoy88nFYMW1F99alQMWXwJAtkAVYKHR8@yt3eNde1PH@wQuEdny/Ayg7qaZVVQQ4CjAMeoQmRgIVQH@kWrMxj6cDAUVyVuxuIDGCXywsLzpq9Auu@S2O@lRGyMVx8eNQX4xPmQNIbw@k1BhNaz/Sf4@HL3CM0A@y8@hyZcwnJkWfDrFXOZY/SLuK2a/NoD3dUhC8DbuEIjysqbKpo@enrpC2wecgE/jZ1HpNIhBOORhXRIdKG7Ld0S2HhVenSkuVSPdISiD1CV6qBnsGuNqQZWx4Qf/V7lJy3STB7FpqoChx9RZBBrCOvs5GjrxfHewdFzqrnD1tazw6dbiBkUzI5qdwH9sK9iBzFNzeCDql@fMRx@L/AuFCyT2vbODuO3xCAsP1SWVx4AtiikRb7TOcLycqKfgefe8yIQR/GhQahodbXhHNyokPtgojDOHIS8FXmuxVAo8jRvJKQBb3Yk9PhoEzkd1aWlOWbSBcJ26UA3k/OTvIfvCWiZdLAs9VyUoy6IXmx@kmapSMfrIx05oyFaxLRuPFz9aqejObSuLKh9QKkZPUpEcJZQRYHP/NIH/IMb3P2xV@Cg04Vp0C34cm8g5kaFRZAeed19Jxk3JCBxLJ6MdOOJlSQWiZT5af8R0VGPioyLEuOpveWpvYXUOMNlb6cFMv389G1EEJtXPbpXPW@5bOxJZlw88e1j1HI96PROH5d7ky2Ecx1qMGwmWuxoTSK87pHXZI@8Xhz0xPnC3d1CmajYqEQmBpxg/BQKc7cL1ZaasW2QOZ60r5GN7c9fTO0aX2ik5LM3nopB8EQpLRCnPTiPfeLE0ELKQEzADWkK4FQkd06Dio8vJRAy2cuPFJI1aGpZWAV0E7hFMOMmykqipOUIRTHkiWxVjMJ21@vkBBkMZnZ3epYKgdCXz6IGplY@N8kTqqKTTiZuEGqkkEBmpQAuq8oyRJC4XYNkGmC3WAbKnu7OL0Z1thiicJ5MpnOzPrI64VY4K0DQD6D3gK@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@SonyebbpnFKQFOrL88F4kQUYli4EBpkifpT211BysJeHwWSeB0i5J4PUXZmPpPbQzIvkZoAiNfHArPsVcStsdfOQQuSBdcVvnhITZ56YGWofLiRBIwpCIJqlfi9MFaIOPK7Ac9cOxeAysxfH4yQUIlYyzLIcAeU70kVvjYPH0H0zZ7BYYV5BOSV7RfWKSS1It0AY@pCGxmhZRbcIl1VWZgu7Fiqst3QiUlgRySvn7KI1Exw9vOeLFpXhgBIXyzHin3Wz7LMuToYIn/AY5dXGPP4XXcAR6pCvG0GP9Mvn55VWAvgvvK@KuUNk7WF6x3iIt@B1crwGgIYABcEts@5dd8JjLS0JcQaEnki8oiTMzj45eyh6PeDXuBiONgg/K3qYAoohLA32DcdDQxBdGhYC9sA@EJ/HDEg@LF6FEoYNUZHgzJFO6lEHBmQyYjxrRKzBwaqQhYQYxiJ4Z2jdxZ3xiafM5mKCYXyYnI/DiyKG@6D/18MZmSzMCFYHzRGJsc6fM@LrvG5/1ZnRQHYbCskN5K5hEX7eCUFMyG@VgicHpIaBvOBrB1wfCMsGQtD2hEE0bOHdfKkhX@@RZZD6Qvhg2eQ7PsHX6dsYk5Y1hqPR@rkwQ@I5LIbUomFIiZnNJrUO1eiQt0k039SQZAjxsfNiPBqeIrJ8UcZpQO7MKDOliqBjtHKDrHF1vqKRRFk8c4L01PCSRmz4NBYepywDPWuIKx681Q6EQh8MDY3fFKg8a20d7Af3Rop7UzTHQi8nZ9kX@Wv9Us9zwNixWIuPN9RDP8eV9zyktfsShjJcRe/m2LHGFyto4n7AN6ROaiPpDUbCZf0mAPd6IPGaeI2Pd62UQODkwpmFYNXhF6BOLKsd5F7FG3hBJ@UZyFLeHcj8BVTMqE2XvHRU19EmWh4j5tsG/AxU3KSfB5U8jyXMH5jaM4h9jLcw5t6qV2psJ5QxulhpKlXaQBOT0XZEIXgFL189gjYEl65OaVvQNtBzNVopIZQE2ohnmcaEmbiuiV9Vz@gyAe/2SLx@EK/REZM6tOSB39pYLqyvErN3xAhH8XD8zuUgrCLF@KnzNSauNqwDNaOuw6NH1rRMrcngHTO6iILr@VG/Du44uH@dhr/EI58PxbXMh6z7mLfGgzY1QLUvWvmRz6N5dGjg1YPXKh2PwLbLa4XVGuN3nBIZYm@huyECiV0bD/HsdlwYgOO4F9fQrjSDlbAZv9SdEQAeuyMoUiwxtNWLgeoBpko1hsmENh6Qfh1ZphQEWZYR9empOGAEGjXdFsWUABvdMCdGFaxM4S3GBU0CrgU/m6zVMi1ryGrg6OLVjjQY4GUdXgw8WV7NtjGCKjVTbWkTnjV4QtZpTz70Y@z8DX9RPq4nsnR2Ct38nHkTFPF6jEoBXb/Bc1/34uPIgWChGR0YsPmsBowIadYSyii3EgA0jmEpDudwuydNnnsgXWv/AK02lCD02GHKD8Ei8k1YUn3hmpI0C60pAZaAi@iRMGldfz7vWUaSW3gKv/fyJMlDyWqU4u7ARMRHvbRfHd76hR5ffbJBGx0YbVyk6pSwB1Jkpc5uPUBcA4ISDq4skZPeygGUMG2cmwlWpEDVxz0t7C60oQyU7oGkhkMyw3EpVAxKlCYdb/11K9PByrk3hwX@jULdqw1@aYff/sFk1iPemktU8GW6AuRG3Hmbinf4RAzNkogJpkhecfASNELUwXGJIT7F6YE8otQgrIlkNM36BlWeUW5zBWaBMqdMQ0qWjdkFWt@5@pRlE/GKJ4HE@Jb/QnbSUOr@uQCaORrcoDKS5VFGwywC3zINuH09hr9Co7N54n7vhlGC2Doycrp2jrxOPX80bdwUsky5rVPKHTrukrN4kCNmaX/uWqwzE/HVTkEVof9zPkzUPuvGszw9nDIgh@I5iufZIDVeiX6uxxPrMjXOToB1sNSYVneS1oFuYZyn10koiBZeinkawWDQDttScd6xhXWX8rZVsNa4AQpSa9JAGx7f1IACL@8WtCoW4WsMAGUZAUFDZZ6wS@FUzcD6xpkMhoNSFw0fDWuoZXvxZ8Kx9Qg/jx/Gfxvs/KF6aI2zrYnkrUuBGK1JmqrAX55yO1Ncyt6vUN6Z/E6Vd6Y@/PIuqA@/vLP1@Z3K61uMv6KCwBBDD9RxUGXfBI0aL/3xPLmdYpOhZyEYoXa@no49GuIpc1Ox6YSe2djWcGg5eFLE/BzwNOdkgsJD/pDmJk@jBm5QkPPcfKRUC9D18LwVJ8a7uG2hvJgiN54@zMcvkCcNbtsWYzR5IOZ1suj7r/LUOyQgiaEk7OWxRL98mBTnqVycALHtktYXN1goqbqfcSoo18EYRfZLLzH@GsIRKjotX4TceFGwoiQ2L8oI5Q6MNx0F/eZHEbUu@GM0FtY6mxvLa0SMLVZXepIQsZ34PteSAqk7HpprahF3BnINyRO@Huvbe8cZj8B5Y5ClN5nxRmlQxfb5heDb4uLcQ2Gdwptv6apv2xpd9BmufkcZkN9NixF6Fkr3KF2CVI9HTo@AfLo1b1lcKii@bz/Os5dDBkr@vncj@/NDto2Cf5uuVOe2gFRomBArrJaWPNlpKTBpLxGn94HPuaGPWxyC5KnNQhnYQXqALDxHSxwkf0TkNCdhbxCTFV8Ciauui@eSoGQtLpXH4gfRhjgNE0RECcDbuEDCypIPOj@znIxDuaXchbP7DEhlXm4LczNJexKmM9nW0NRXuCNz3Io4bbuB7GDqmJsd7e@g/fxU@ew16P33kCYk6lFlll9vD0ouLo4GYQf35g/wJHW8DZhTKmjggPIF3ttrGJPsXMzXaI@j3qVeg@5FqjLCZXIiO33QZ69wodHc2DTj1lehqWjrACKCHJBo5d2TiHjoHm32nNRRPzJXgB0S5XAzLc@G1cFZZi/ybE3gmYla10GRVUVaoXymcHuD6K7eLGFXx3vZsOQ@6/WyQ/Zo0hb7eofvytg@xKzY2ruRbnNlG3OTg7akdT9ACtt9DW8xBVg8PC7ALuumDNVmurLVY867kWqjycGyWSbpxASP5yPNkViJMy1HCQZVjwAT5TVmhZAQMIqfuL9tiqw8ex2aajyeR4t18NSipCPOEhI2I6zbsO0HrSY5BvzKN8jA8GxwXgw1RHhC6neW9UYG8mJrmMMw5ITRwobfULBsLzf4zqxIMUMvESDOWKOhIYxiGYrtY0jRMC5GYs5p7gdfn4HGpBYAyxza17FC9etXGlRlpN4i0zu0KSiwX0Aw2c9TSG@OB9PDtRa2JlQIjFOQspTILFoaimexmpYphzFzsFnEAIdg0kPbr/H31H4MBSATeQ8wmOEQL1b1bjenrAvtE3o6lRIJWRQF@MBgZLiqqVkjx5j8XRNCbIkOahayM3hN6PVr8RoVx1EN49pZHk84Yfv5A1ruhmsTUFEH5l18VsOQ@IlgNdhwA0uMs8wQ22CcrHcEGk4TpU4w7JkIw8HRWxMwFQKjE0NLDy4TcGmPV5YvGwDWSdvFTDdH8bwFdmrHHRET7Vu4uILfeZvFpQ4DYCPgT02CDBvLgsitoWbzxIDaJtaIeeOza4X2LwKDDDYQ6pCoGPoIP/JmLBbSPR9IAA/iDqHit4CH4gD7hYwDeHD3PB/e2pqwUeDgxme36A5XSIGShSfi1vkeuCDB75wan4VDmy8mibin4hVycToaJmQl4@vsU8tCv5c8RX9q/ROJzJ6ty4PlBCXW9uNMAq2qmDXLeQqsXqeFFim9gSs1NnCHBfRLAD3Vz5cbONfCV22Q7Qxb8RoIRFPtTh@KBO2lI8G4NtVTV@9StYEOh2Zv/3wGhwF6PMZN4gK0ORq0NbwQhOrL36ZJ8x5oJAeQVIBaopSDrZc6cTg9A/R8hks9yX7clfy@xZMivQSVHwD07Ug4goo8kf1SVAy@Byub/NrppcQrmkKKWC34fio8ZeXcO2RjJqh47h3H4at8xfo0RuUOjFJgPJvaEoYGLze0xOnasi/5zBGa3Yjzu6pOdm@cC@QLljGSZ9HDSX4nCOMzGZ5xLjirifozDix91b3fyOtRkwtM0eAbevjGqaCC@RxePVi07K9GLnDaAhbW4RaovAjClVE8Lp@55IzdJx5vzpXbEPneoEJ465ao60a4K/C2FqZMvq/NNnpCuorQhoAUFIHQXs7R/C5Mkl4aMqEhKJ55ruNQ5jMND6wutjvJYZ9bVP95Pr3qE7Simc2C1xs5fTQanDqCNPxFwp3QUt20t72BryeLVD8WedLwT6X5bvVGHIObU@tsLNZ30U6rMV/htTSlfzNe4lMUSZeWJp9SO1QX/jLxwCYfJ2oW3YD0Dn8xYJHTxpSW5zHGHu/6c7aqiEWe/AwXGN4ZnhAjtm/Aa9gY7riSP10vOqjj5hyXaCc00suc@wB9z@t3quFYMEhySc2YiF7v0Hzhp83EeD2QJy/6XXvUw6zgTD/ECTaozO5OWe75LIeW5vIJf15TBE7rDkeIg/d/KbRa0DslhO9aASjasiJm@EXEU88mjujFMuqesJHxErB0SyQryiDyQ4WgCe/94Og50qo@t7ULeBzpmKOuk0R5yZ/5zsV2uDHx8GD/xcnuUeto98vdo@NdikkL@f0NxaNhnixlzjWeWGAKvEknfNZdLvbK1mEcxxGHDo9DDfy4Y7ku2wN1VwN1/FKFmOpIiy2ccy8@Wxz20tHsGo9/woV52nxPK40dHbcIjXCpEpTvmivgfHo45Uic@GEMxB3@qPSjROwddhdDngnMnIcg/8Se1LbopFaCEDsbcEixeu41SoBCm4jOMft3dOXEGlsPGk0OwXkJ/oEIKABAOK66neTo2olwX4WK10DmRDES88rPdgfde7vADnmyO5Qs2@HlQhlSNSzzIiZOTwjlgCQ3GLSyeKlFzati2hQESeC6Beg6VNO8RLxAedQP8kqukP/1HWkQTGL/A51W8B225H/Hfd6z@/TnHgo3b9u@d7BJSMa5ndpDFzkLbu4OuvlH0EU31E0lVBQJfbft5It3kwv0pX/gHeQLNpCL3JX/fjaN/3r3cz94m/WvfMbC3/82nLkEHNmV45Hv3CWmt7@@DTv/X9k18mnbRe7bRfGPWyfmb50Qp0R@yuaJZDpJq49R8tg/4AZ7NDX55h/HW90tzmibksk8rhVZaOsfyxVdNB8csiVWIj9sEX1kBX1kWfnf2XL4xWWdsxcgKO78ZcefUOrQ5ohIQQuftBLeP33sniXu4dX6t5H8e@mGl@3jknZ7grJnYEjDPieyG10iTdzmwwcWWQbOd7rwNb5E/mKFub@9Rax7DxvjvMXoYuzwbGY85tTyd24UnBPbP7nSFQf/8TMDo@dmCmoN70kUcIV6ZEG80KMkD9ftbP1NLVsPajAwltIhYmEjvshrKo11g6fr0diAew@k6TaKoAyMsYtQRpvGa4tFiYmONrMnxJ@B///LbiufBPkGj3/cZPUPuMnqH3eN/OOukX/cNXLXrpHEcn7k2Pm2buZBNDOYfA3SP90qsnPAXj3dOmEnT3fZ3svt77GvD16yV1svTvCqz8OXT57tbzP47r443mX@BaX0@VKzcck9g6bf0ToaWeeLhUKZEeaZWxfK7FgdsKdWR7sC4tlw1MHjPn/JmZrb5LF2rzR7YvHpoCEuZnHFrgmyFfG5Js/ihDuu20DJA5xH9M7yxDzSaZ6Od2sgdDa648HfwM3n9kgGoXVcNK3kb9oAeAt8AY3Kp2Rp7TROrZPQ0s0xUXH@55NrEITC58ds68UOHl@8s3@yf/DimO0dHMHr4dd4zA7b2cdjY568xCACfH6ws7@3v71FHjwDhRxD2xptWL8rCzkEp1rpXPZGncvc0ECtULxFrvVIxGKm5e2KcFhyZAbH93SBpHDenR92igYnIOyVraPPv0SpRnvH4nE8uZdfcIpcwNuBsFLATSOQmrgaoE4wJFrKCmdIgwlbweA6XbKaIneWecglmifWNRbfRjMiTkjzu1hJYPNQQ0LLgBtReQfBNthbEJBTyWR2g1A2ITWyHnipoWG1571g1MfiYFbUIxPeKa0OIcUTZ/fNDj8b3PMAuueruilZ1@YAaBASHhwAbTDo4aqX2j4aSVhFQIxcVPzBY5V7vB0M965RasQNrsLjCUpCdBBEqBWpSVXWtlXd5O0Y2dbEuYPqdHSdojgEj4fkGIZncqUlcSD/izk2nJUFyDhwwR70bE@pCKbdgBqAt/fVnuuwVENCazCoIJqp85VaF4YK6h7ZhW3csHSFywgo2Srect0QNzcFAiedLuypMO0Ji@bDj7cjBn7tofEg5pOZFHHdHhUaF0ypXNq9NwNPZjLwXdAAIjnML/BYoaHL7ydFNFZPkHLKsYAi8bKnb8LwQM7dUUeLRBC6Tuqt/v69JCo5G0QJLfGh3Pkr7N6OBkOcCLnGM6jomAtQYmilZB9no3gbpqIlCOaGB7gYwsYMvmk0I6mFlQcvRbESRySK8vyCVNsqbYa7N1WieL422GdfQ//MKJr@dvi2PJomaaOa7GtzDp7njIsY8GQnG4956TFcWDRxKScoedVisYB3fMOc/OnraqO58@RM/uZN9jyfv@BsQe3yyQu@KJFPs5BKDt3DXztJqwG9niaQxpz/p71ra27jyM7Pwq8YDWVhRgAGBEhKJMGhqAu9VkoSFYrKuoqCsbgMyJFADIIZSIBJpLK5p5JK1WYdb9bZS@XiTSp5Tbb2UpU85N3@D/sL9h8459Ld0zOYAem1a5@CBxLoPv316e7Tp0/fTk86mFqeZ2Rtib1cgoHhcuqD8b3Xaqg4XlZdDMcX6tLhFHhx4XKqCt03IRGahKdWrN3KxrHMskxpmoYtAGLdCcyiZ10ZUiZMpa/38LEObIUG1MgQ9Qgdr9FKy@drNG/XuKEHmqUg7DRuboVvywcWhETRx9Lbo/qBdd8t7dpVSUWdSVWnJVV0WSLXbFEqeqiExqsFuIfL4UB/Xx1ucyl3PDx8KbSHS9G@FG@VUj4WD0sa1tVh/2AJLA9uvxEslL2cD8yD5CKaknQlnOUbK1LmL8nxWwttR30PYHDsHQWjGFTLbTIcoIc4ixfFgTVKYOswsUH0/Ojh/uGhYdITm9uQFvQevvTYE2oQsa9LT0d8D5mUnaOMJvmJjScZIp7iSWa7rDNnVl6OqhA2SFnUh1IW8aPffX8qbkfwyEImBF68ZoUoay7J3bnUQeGxAJ4f40koI240rYCFzGKu8ODDTvZJycT1VmbbOHztj5Qx402Fsy5aqh7PdCBpCONw0D7Bne/s9vsm28fbMh82sLzfn1CB8RB@F/3lG88h4xHuFDvJFlzSLLJJ6cwKSemKrDu6lpe0sL@6QKkHJubCFtbUujCOBWtsH9@QZg4ta@IwgPv8MxHZPRPrnVLFU8iO3qB2POhZySEIjEyYBht7ulRA8uZcDGFUG2qcdJVBrve1G8TNseSyiWeMBHYjn@gdsOA3bqfVQzor0LZLs6p8PVnxKJHISdZ5ZmFkJCDf3thYuww7XQqZvPJVsXkMSevP6Gz0pq1BhrOQjgqB5D56WpbxsQAsqToXZoE9S3aYVEIwdTLGlETZaTDS@QNe@FVqYObgxVEZ14vSudrGNMVbNjqPSDo6kSyUQevCqqDcaxZqf748O1TIl@Z3/cvnx50NiXA9fP4FPzh7GIxQVeKz4S32igpT8u0QT8VFmIIfWleeftnDHiHthRFPX4@b/Jt3uPGONOe4FwWv8Vy/K1I54WgASsnEbSjnrD06v8AFrgtaMuU4vBMg0vplY@8Vn1FZ5ZBeQIcIyKmBYIC4TIaBmn/TUvcLIW4bjw8W@JVPJNA2MF1VgcWbRQPmPdu4qlCWYSUOA/tEBVU4SL50rcJvcTjeS/BHg5kKr3J4z3vjo5tsEbojUN62RypsV1BOoB7wzJeKMAUxrdX6/VmLql1F3@VoMGNU0DuCGZhbDgIVep1D8UyVDDoWaSdxUJODYCalglYEFQ5MfqTLUuh5r1vUyAYPCwBYLBtDf9B0xPmpu5aYO9riCkfEDQnpvWGvQI2CIhZDySFhD13LChE63vObDh2gFAoI52Rxw3JH2vPjBDoxhIN@rclfJFScjBjAv4IJwaouvJjz8d4rlPCxF3YnnqFegU9IJTkGWcH3oYyDd43Dg2f7SWjkuIU2CqWSB/ZQBI8FY1Qc2WXL0ODBJDptcaD8mY5963GshODfimgYjDUi/pmOlRkQRBO7pXF@0bswjmHwHqlGsXp2UzS6LLEqg9MNJsPo/GJ6Qc07BUvPARG4a8wdXCS4u1AtoicKC1uKA@3Ftc@8FtqVLelWIc6FQiiXqfDNEYgb16k@b88L8lVfqT@h6aBnkpJWWhG9RKAmCNDk2R7jgkHoQXV0TxXJmPayXXzlM8UYDkqOsxBcMu7YtkjuSZW0mNkVMynlZbIVZ8ISpnCcEEKsODfb6AXGhX8Rv4MuBxUc@jfTsx1V2@i7WTSjNsRQt0vQrDa1aN6V0MrcKyS/LXQ40YLxffBCjCM6BLSeps1dlvEEGcn3AplSDpKMO9ACHfWCBCF3kwVCSr@I2MrmMu56GUmyOY774yI7ObnEcBlJsnOJmU42RdzXU63RDcA64wdJ8EsLJoLa@JrZciA2CxnndVYjnVCIIk1nWpynxf/sjDykmmYKkMem/FprNsXrunqypfTJGtE5EIXXKgR1ELlTwWFND6@lw/UhydjVkqcpNKZSxICZGqkubwv2JJIIeos3tbhb0aUt/hyjrSWGRlA5TY2URCiHtJIk5V4T0wIpkpAVhyOLRso9MUlayibVhJ/oddQUr1pvVKSlbFKtfyygVrJQk6SlNOmCXiNFmax7ZdDespY3np1jx@pwWlbe1OtOIh5ppNMK6EMRdA/d0BLUPf/Ej@4asaFF3xzgB4V2fVN4xJZhMMHfuKNMH0ogTW2dBZFtDIjaQrOl/IyMeTlKN99iw1wZjwl6fJ2Bxjed9Jgo9GYw2AOTYEQaGWJCI0cxaYrpVcOpppHRoMtIhmmsnMPPOVq/xyvnPN1xaN/RLJv23GS2GgktCmWSwWJ@tLMj68KJgpZvZH4agnnCCEZGEsOJg5Z8EhiTSIXiEkd5EHR5sbOMWA05WTuG8KZ4dDONgbspi2WRCQGmeTkfuKGyiDGil4CXFUrHkJOqRYxbV8aQE7ZFjMrV@aD5VFZZ3rkyBk8EszCqV8ZACVysU3PlHADm/NfMErVEfeC1KBHaLneSoqEw24lfnXRZ5FTVwPuChJCgn6Z@ZfEhDHNd1gfaNOhK9YGTjsX6sHzuSbswFJPmXuUF5hqmtBf6C09uKZRXYLWe1zBuhFEPBgKnP1D9O6Pzp6boqUUSAUjrHjiJcbqnY5giYWs6YvYhDRDCBP5bLTya1WrRytCzw4NvHN570np67wlOolZYR@HyDZ6WoeM6q07dhChebWnRmSLXwKMWWIwC6WEtjvgTMPs0itDLsZhq5Vyjm5tsQGFOLq0XOUPvrfEuRDm0M5jGREpHrc1A81jEg1LqZuWNaceU@ggmSyXma7vACdGwnAhOiEYLLmiTLU7/csgnVF4OX0ZM2DGO@U5m2NT5fYkXl7SEhlF58zL6PW/cwbMkFeW0lFsRj@Dj3I2cU@GRC7GCHiNoDfhFtWrcl05xxf219qCLLm8nfXJ8e@YP2medXtsZnY4K/dAV7mmsYj9EJ5cFPEz16Gj/8HnrGb7Ttf@Abk7gp0FxR4@e7B@8OMKY5xC1JoL3Dw8PDlt0QP3wxbMj9BiaCjJ1QoESk4mABNHTg/fuPdZo@LcpmOQLISHMN@GfcOVTNvxRa0p/Z3TNo8xHIVr0CA9dU8GkFFY2Iv/MCyby8Tb0PyEH@DLePMFNGchLvmpMDmksXP4UcbGv07lGRXyMJ6OISOkEvJWqCTuZgmnOwhNMQL6IQrDb6TS9wyvKGIcX@YKRlUqLF2QwWUHc7@qH1DuwmzyfDbuWhBOOPMvn3hAocbepOIn6lc3i3EavkiM6NJROXKzCyFEl56jF7JSiBsWp9IL2iJG@7NooyAvvQEU3SqgR4psplIB3EBtGqeTb5wX9gSgRBVqV3486N7Q79Eka8X7NNa2N2K0pn/OF/FFA1DdxA0fJCP98pm9KkYCJ/Sm6zHGMN89VndF/WVheYbZU61ghPz4v73U7eHrkATB8L7LY0Qv57IvlTmx3CQZaGJFu8WQcwIu9MVFgypBlPIwaUFHReGbwDcIwUtUFJW/i36lw7drFAzQWCJyt05omx7I7SrwkFEZMQNM8c9fcjt3Y8LUEdXCYKXZ0iloWxQc6RT2L4o1OsZZF8dlHTOL3rVJJNt6uUd/Y4NPMifbMSP6fKnmlIml35FHoODHg6cnlaMwg@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@wPW6fDtv4QGsYDB3xAogfVPfPglc@DlTjKrq5cF6FebOhr2JaEwDN41ycvt7DAxXAqnAqwme/ed6OhO1ud3I2GeAemivmVegYqVpFl3E0ERxOzkKBiSPu/Yk/gBK4aKnFJiJM80bAJY3CYEpfKftU1lnZLmZZrfK5cYfc0FEQ8dYd@6OIMnMX5wLo8okMVMjC39FopQmPF9TPCYhd0bqiPI/9oWdp9PiKq1/WAsgvQsnlVA2SjHSdaBhlPAHydHKWQDgXLU5nY1yOcUK88WOtlutYcx7KjTH28IUQdTvCD4268EFHrmUQRNwgGidR6uV1m2uJgJ6BeJ4lKdbL9VXMaIRR5KKIPEOrk@XtPrktokuthEFoippaASzCGF7U6@4qlA4iFF@u@esff/SPpn1ercowelPHH7ZhzkAvksSo@PMoeCZ/a/A4PxF3FVPY/xRjM3TP6/pnbXyhJtKgQbhykKEBEfkcBA2dVgUD0DfBiaX5gpEZomBVq/cePjSO3js8@CbehuJFBJKCVHIUgm3DLHG1U8pEvDgYjCRCEhZpnoiMkUgysUilSoVkqsTkXqdvaSewoLa@8@dUW7SWH@BJd@6XKUCMNtmpD64T4tlaHVY1hJRgbIfv/BkjByM@PZsNHIxMIZjwdeSB8MulSGuhXEyRnd@vfvBXlJ24UQI2H66rnOlZ5xn9FHssFmRJZiu1Zm6pEtlQJeQCX1pF3/0JgYX8SLdUhIVrulZUINnF/tHfGYSBmw/QelpKI4FTuhToYwZSuwdUc7l4lUvxvsd4PZ92AXSgzixZxCcwTjpjvDRkacHVS6rvVz8QHAO9H@GeyZI8biXYLWQ2xn/oLUtpRXPkta@Gn9vCP9RBxTXXPEQeqDJxPvpl3E31YrLrZJbva1rvTLGWWeCPfpElfXTGHHoPegBnWL2pMvtKDs9/87cKf1q4Nr1EYH79408@jcs4zS3ZNLc8n8S9abpYimke79dSKul9HDLM0jS3KX6ezCbRc6eu9jMP4Gd59T5NVvY0r8uD6KtOP72k2@eBfCxBVIefXtrl87C@J7EyO3u6WDndfZrbzSV6TkdP4d/KYRM647/rnXG6rOVz@3y@WPwDgaPBh5dHF5qlWhUWziqZtjtGjf6jZ178v5vmRtd@uNQWGy4uWFQAh7OmhOwh1XRH7/nn6Tfl52zXxKE14WxBlkjLpSZygalJexBmZOW6X1tedaw6mO5l5LL7m2VSmFerQ48v3U9GPZx10P7dGc08xrT9h48HZGvGb1NbgrUN0xW@bUPuCY6J5Sbt4IQL4oNw5HNITjXQA3QPphv0f0cVt1LjEJpvXEujDAI2ia7RcjpOhXInImImUao1MycVPE/N7Aj/qjQQz646PLvCyhJlJD@yccylyvu7nyqNpGopSKKnIEuXY/6LaAY6YkR75eSxQ9h0@dBu4peaSCVD5RCQO3T/m64tUtnl25IaWR7y9/9CDXReiGdZe1AevPJKHv/xcUysmNwRUNOf/JUALPtWrDJyc/5L2fAha6i8zHEku0I@Odn85E9MFO3sSuLoxuWTLIGYO8cyHj01XjzfPzQOXhw9e3GECzK6Y0Q1B8@f6PG0m/UyTWCTiwQLc9kGTPPrPJ3V4li8/LJfqttU/L/@BIvPsCXXXDW1alqa7oeJdDWZbkkdUVNcuYZE/Syk50UL4I7zFqV13U1RQzCBfjSMsL@GHnwRZLwwwQ6fxdjG4s9XpvVZt8iYca7Q9F9nsbTFmPzFBBzqsAHcmoHt567@v2T8diSDlqxmuHvnZu3mMT6UQrr8JNLftgQlVjYbhS@@WDFGs@g0GNYLK4ZafzVo/RV9BvEq56uQ13DDoT8aeRE9RWCceENcgMbH2fwArQp00IG@7@H7a4/uAG9LcIOXS1uvwhYCtQSQM5oZ5o09s1Dwz0bBODI@HPgd@R3fEb29Ln@FsxBdPYSel/UY9dF49ig6GKLtUEWvhlHA3/V3qdHdUghVDhR@4Iwnwyq5hPCGPVy6pqOC7dfA2ilkB0XrtYCshcWybNw9Dj10IWW@nPb7Jl2w9ga95x5WLlp4hvJ2/ggv85nA/KmJJ8xWjKdB5G3zlWh5z1h50qAa94yiWDCrDPjNRVrVL2qvceCpNHxvinZPTDy4JNbUyT2P6dAiMaQybVpit/CcVj8IopheHrcQCXjzJpECy4gP6bDwot/fuET4jJeHpz8FEyXDEAHER/xTZBoHUEbEDWiccnuMHUfdqwEjcCbW/2vb6IIL7Vkw17fl@WMfzzLXNrfRfzaVBCsUm0ks39Y2MWbCD67jqzB8f1wvR8kVnAAhNwg9VgT9AF@oDjqv6KAHGtQww0b5c2QcmhAddFsyID/saGOqp8Xfdnx2197zQyLAlNWTD/2RqKJyQlQ7k5PQ4b5A3s/9MJx4G3c214khentAkvaCboK0XgVkdP9WJeZOo7OBKsVWdCre1CYfLWfy0W3ylAWdkuQMfSG08VweCOBtm0QHqjJRUqgFa6vMYQ/3331872j/Ydmo1DaQnC@RKFpLq1yOLlE8HbIUYoRJuPs6ndvrLORWWC7uVYu2YH1Pr/aSzrAEAHNrjLp2ZBVdSiasZwYGtdZDXVVWbyKp91fwPBV2N2RlMkbPwqasXNnzV1ZMFGnMawVFMGHXQRq7oK6ewC9QPAtEuboCakBotxZOedDdP0muuXO9UlF9apu@VUCxViq7fBfMfABj5WujeDgZJrRtkfpO2yiCkkOPNqzarhdJLzhmwzh1i@@ExUYXxnNlILyxJva5fIZn2EcuLK64o@D@TLafNZE7S1Ah9nGtadsioPi//1O0G/P46N7AiuxzHOI@dKXbNoeV@j57ubKKPGODZB86EUw0H5ByjdyooRJ0gt7MoWfDeg9OYWJhfajnMbLsczqB1HXdNfscshyP8KzoCJShdwSIdgPD@okw@AF1DDZG9eXLIbquu4X7dO8/efweNPkh@oAIo@MPmrduVMvFIswmaJfQRW/cxsODJ89wtB/bDo3678JwLepl3FaZOLj4jrd7iPuyiUWrYi8EzXniRaL04f3ZUfvkKZhjVrENVZA0str6zhw@RYvn7fQ6cs1k44KNdOIS1enY6zd403keum@sE7sRwb9TPYsNyMKt1wk9gkQuXvJL1bo/hNH6vaMnj93iTttAVDejVxRLHSUcICgkMBYG0Tw8ITr45B1KVcR3K0hg4FMqmrvJsuxU27vFxnyey8/joN1jrxzFWIB71qQsJG7sLjZpYxxLwWzkuRjAQ9s39o/MMqQdTzwbA@kdghkpLXYY6Mo8WNxQU9AQOHuONK67fvMmhWGSSei69dVVG7dw5oBG9zQBljvWuDEft92epSqyPfIdmt56U86LjJO6U6@2h@FbbxxWa7frqxt37gZjnNv3vLB7MwQV4rbx2Tc/mt3Ey3a05XsSDPo3@/4AF5Wur9/aPPDv/@77W89vP7S6nd@pmWXzVUjv8I5HOgPj9luxQw86dtxl6SImhoDZbVdH7ddBdb232t1c3azd6Xl3NrzN1bXN7oa3ttXZ2trq9tc3O72tO@07G91OFV07UhLnjDb4TRZ/zLZ/tWzzDLPN@upWv1@r3b7T29jqb9VX19bWO5sbvdX19f5mrb22drtX3@xsdZZbbTE/BVCwUu/i2JHWwO/kG3eFBd0uUtv/Bw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#  ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>  ;
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}  --[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
OOO    program-id.h.procedure
231    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
uuu # >>IF 2>2
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
  
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/=>+&&1=1~-<>8;t$f U=B~+Num 4839195>E ngt;reaeidgenulohar Cr#ataPr$s?6 8<<
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:!*z(\,_)?218:sizeof' '-1?67^*u"":*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0,)[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h  (0::Real a=>a))  -(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num ()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint ("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Gofer is an early implementation of Haskell language.

Gofer code is blended with Curry and Hugs. The three languages are separated by `length (show "\0")`:

```haskell
        show "\0"     length
Curry   "\"\\00\""    5
Hugs    "\"\\NUL\""   6
Gofer   "\"␀\""       3
```

```haskell
main = print $ [233,0,146,157]!!(length(show "\0")-3)
```

Polyglot uses deparenthesized version of above code (see line 113) (golfed by Ørjan):

```haskell
l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l
```

Note: `l=length.show` doesn't work in Gofer.

Removed `w` from line 38 to fix Grass.

Some Haskell/ghc [golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/171659#comment414348_171659) by Ørjan Johansen.

Comment: deparenthesized → обесскобоченная... скособоченная

Comment: [`l=length$show '\0';main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X1c3RyHRNic1L70kQ6U4I79cIdE6NzEzz7agKDOvRCXayNhYx0DH0MRMx9DUPFZRMSM1MSU6R0E9xkBd1ziWi5B2Ax0QRDcEoh@ombBSiH1I5oN0gu21RRclwt0gJ3MR0InDyf//AwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## 234. [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 10919 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JAryNZwEoPEgQIMBm83Ev77CbHJJ9@94hedEFoEBUs1CFriqQQLN5YzTrGGtWCod2dqwYSd69I9lay96NWIXDjtDGamMjpK8biv0NrU8OhcPzD@RzTmZWFV4k@85Ish0CCVRW5smTr5Mnzzn5amlu72//NoYfdmSb40vT9pinux7rOMa17mTZszF7qhluuVCMRBBqy7kc9nXLc6uRGFMZs/Qbtm@1jQ74Mc@@0i3jne5AWIGxgWNfOlqfeT3NgxcDYrEd3Xzff@@xtt3va1bHBcgiY0caBHaH7SumtVzP0dqeYVsQVGLspWVq/VZHYwChOwNH9wh9mbENvT/wxg14WWXsue24OqbY1l3XRoi1MEQFIDTHsA@2Xnw6hWmdsU81yMzA1EdTyat59srQnc5UDFVlX5zu7U37Ftj3FNtie1iMqaAie@m4mqlN4y@xraFn73vT/mW2dalbGitk17OF6cBV9szRZqKsMUfXOl3D1LOG1WYK6@nmQHcY@rCu7UArebpZyVfyza0gZraNcStB4BTauvwwzbl0IdC@1sGpQ/sNDL3Duo7dZ5rl3kBK6no@gEe068wsFr2puijkQ81SUMMvhfBLMfxSYupBc5oECmX03Trcn/ZfZYWDab81yHH7qjvbNoUKO7YH42nfdfbcOJhHeMU82@3bb4xtuwNlngoLF6dYmOwAbWgf6FrsjQtZ6ejMtYzBQPd4ILS27lAwVDwzDesqwvvbkWN3hm3DugQ4HZIbDD1qUjfShmgNNhC9NosOFiMi4GCQhRO7r4ez6EJ3hUZzB3rb6BptThv6yNMtF5rbzTIDqufGME3W0U2IEGBvZ5hrs6Eb8mqZWi/bzkaQtjAV1r8ymcHagwHjQVAMyNJevsJ0rDD2DsLNnstGgz5zjT4Ee22729V19k4f9CB6pGNHGHzag6li@W8rOsBYuqwafQB9GqvGxqqGepI1dONoULeOK@rAM/pQs4YXd5muuQbyN4ji6laHanXgcz4baDlcYezagD4LRR86hNvVHeo1hBd6mKMDSs1v58SNY3hQm1gbW@xI1xx26uh6krex7ra1AbZwOElIzMYUPCxIlhp1YyO@e7gXh8blMbLaABrTKZ5@//OIxrJ1ttKswbcejdYiuy922O3KObo5hwUCGDgJLcnq3zA3d36uw3ektnKXzl0EsEagVkyWswdeTlMGkEHFgwzmNHSiS7kuZAdmKGG2MdUWIZLjUB1oDeAf7IsMlaw9dBwcC4JK1a6g0KZtXUJ9QmGdoYX1YbHVPDRB24ZBIMP0a6g1YJ7URvYN1fBpz4BGc7FJQkyJD09UoTBAARmLGpXpurY5JDiI6XpIy1ArEBUx7nfZF6yrGSZGgXBExXPt6O7Q9DDO0Opgy/cNS@9kmcwG9VgH6PgaktMAKXkA6fdD/ZIyBcDQEDYVFYM@/M4fdC4vAc9Wu207HUGuX7CO3aaBVKPMwlDIkGBtSzMpWwCXwdR5dEjgWjONDnEIzRqLJCgTlOqNPTQ7zIYEnRsDemlPAz6tQ@dqezoncnvoQR4zrK9dcW5icMqFgve1FjQsJUBpU7EV9nQbWqmtR2JEM0p/6HUrTBnssrib@zqxWU1sLp/rkLlkNplayeUua0Bw2RR5wVv8Psr5YmtilHE9zbWNTmQw9nq2VWBKm0XbdXugW4n4BI54Ju604skscrlEsmbU29muYXUS8Q2gxQYkHE/W2vX2mVG9qE1FDycJaG4QDXZXPdFORiPAcqhTXOf6IIpkYTz4QhGuUJjtNrHKMTgb8saKmfa75h4xEnSQLm0kEOBDWdfU9UEin1WTyCYQbm65MWBeSadwiAJXjYt0PBZPh4tOGKCkEwXFznpq2Mi2zEEPh0OoFMsdwEjgIO22NaAeFwcEDwTADGsRXdMoApyFeOKNHgcBoAWMVNIRdUne5TC@goxSYAi60GRP1juhjgxMAPqy585wY9NGwYLyhMMMsA4LE9UuoWkgMi/IFi8IT4l8Jot0ZQFDQWwtnVWUlgGdALsb8HRB86GyAXixwGEAG@8kId7T18aApc2H1aDDMKMLfakP7MEZs7aOPAeYj84HFExkSP3PBSmZ2V2WVwrl8mQfm@linpPbUn4ATPpd7t6ehIUPdyZkNKwLQrmpWZdD7RL4hW1BFK3d1geeYFRQEtcDVjQ93pCnIgbPrNuLrDydTpsGESlaBGkgk@etJ4ZCDbmLEPIVkGdQauSaA@sYDrAlczydOgBcTyUefY0gExl4HV2QBSkBAJHpI7099ICrAQHf9Ix2D2gWc2dxvsgHoenkwSucOnB2pesnjZlRG08KkWzO98JsLEShYIvO4oHBFVE1Jjyo8cMe92PW3P4cxLafRRgIQr7ZnJYF2nsAZ9@27DlIoSJ9tAgyGcLbASSxExQoYeCSYhd1Vl/K9JsI2gy4BvR8oL@e5w3cKowThtcbtrJAKblTZ7zvHVpILDnPGRuezd0t024BW3ahf@ZkCrn2sGWMpgpEfn4bvnEj1yCAdV1Wh5H77RCoLhHvusAwyX8bgUNBUWLchIL/RgGQgLJQUYmuS6x4D5jKydhqJ6ITRBnNsCj23WgSHBjRr5rPUXibzOYb8JrOJYKFM5PNIVTOddrkUEIyKaJHcMpWZGmiaI/MY2QpGoWfrma6OjytoWni69DiXC7BZYUku40sLQFrS1ByRn9gGm3Da/JQ9uSJkCnYMqiHKDZ1UWZKQpwloYdngaEAjBh@OHTWs09I2E0koSBLdxMJ645jOzxdr@fYN4w8ECwSrtRtu4/cnb0igQslaNCIDQu1OzGW0lCqzRUh/DGV5OV4PPvGNqzEbXx5eTlejTdgxFxe3gTXBro20ZUG1ya5FHIhXBZdFCNDLgw9oxjodxG/O5OYR8kL7A4jHO3fGYOEdlatFi8y2pkqngV8JqGeYcQAaAUfgCeerNfRmUxGGzdQ0GyrO1n6bRz1TtqOMRCV8Ll2rfF3UQtFqgZoONtBxaCGwsv9ddKvOyBdgDLQ7iWc@PlZ/vzi/Pa8kz6/i2cwdrKm1VtQKEgv0c9eOvYQxJDkWamqqBfJ5FkRhI9WPZ6PpxKJimJCQloy@UklmdZ4bSfiOoyGifPzOFSqqJ@zds8hfKNMIZn0qwrygQIPyNqJePa2Aum3khfJdBziJuMZUN3q8TjUTBsrwaVCY1@aqKDD4@/xitlOpyPUvW3nCr8zwyn4ZUFxnYx@NHz3DnkXx9HyKcwcalzKGwiA3L4lYbMYOKW8yqBWlyEfnUjjU7vLtaJt/Nk92IvoI2qtTw/3do/rlExPc69AplAuETYHsjLUitPJAjcwhx09Mg8G2Aa42kFOUO/GxC/bbabYjMCUNs9EaLhoswXYgNeQ4GkzxexPFsHtQX63J8pASMifYt4nv7Rlljj43Dz5Se4Bx94@mbTt9K9AnmBt10ThW3F4AeA1l@KeHXr4OkaV7ZOOZoGACbQF8mXHtwVYtqUgL5TqnB1OiAwgCEF@KG2hJGFMwCDirjEClRhGurEU/VFiRel/27ZAOdWzr4gbRhkwcrT06Nm58v8RF6SybTfonSDpg3Ngam3g95PozqPsHBACB8rl5ockazOIp5UD0uMfKiOIUm3NwvrrGKSnDg23h9ULugSOAk4XahWVVJCGdaq1fdYGKfcSalofGR7XWqGHn2CUzzQ3kUQ9aYvrGUhlKCNjpqTViwRYuw0avg6yMoZycwnbta4Nx7awkrO7gBpYUQ3bYAr5vOoFMtra2i/sLK7fecihxma81VDdhrFOV27bhd5l2aZ9abMUACBpZrOcsPcttA6CluNpA@hRxjuqoK1L2xpP0aCu@@bW1aKvb2oImSP47BsYBdj8QgcAC8p8sv@DXRBD1HI@D/mXb3n6@IUMYZkuI3q2WQAg5gxMpBtsyR/og954wmqK9MHtJkBPts47JrdkaSBCQq5ED39HUcOdnPtAP5dBHemaV/Zd0gnQeBfWqydKPyGt8G4DJYxNeaOvrIoJpDMNHrQvMq7z3ATf8k0FSrdve1ruiyywaPyJoISsGCzq5uLL8Zyi4G@UglihwXId/TqHXCrAPNrV23Nxj3S9ncNQHNyYdMytHhm4oGrO4WPRDxSTP2Ud@DGny3@ZTiNjp9z5afNMwyB/2hvqEb3ds1n0HFSMcMmiMED0QFdWoOZBAES9xI8m5o8inj0Eta6jm0bf8PbJ3m1aqLtkiXlnkWuJULTUBwiODB0Ecm5wCAYZtEkHY5R1yeGPgZMTVlDxs7xKHb2TSwXYntu2A3qly1SyKRT8qu@LgJztDjpZbwQIeKxdGt9dOc6/ONzZbR5tnX5Wzw1dJ2caLeARHb3ZB2XWhO6w4IN5QwvhLtCOYdl9A0okUb67Mo9t2@PCAxrdH/eJYUSJ42CnebD/7Hjr@CuRORrRjf7Q1DCP1ZUpAB/HCcHci6Ztt2yQLazhQkwgXBw@OzyQWD5/ebC/1dzZPTo8DaF5MzQNTR3lBleXiwr0OYIwNZvnVX9odiZnQ0hNnbAiCGaDOleNgW7KFAV@FfTjiaJWlsUAFJFxeFQUtAJraOd2WEHNr693Wlqloq922qXSWlfrdjqlglopdyvlQjkPP2ur6zp7T@CKoo/IcgMubhVBAxKmAZmnh5otiSzly1pL1edmigfdky29U2lXymVNb5XabQ1y1V4t6qVuPr9e0gsFvdQqdVVNLRTuzRZPRcpboBi3QX4az82QH3pPntrlsr5WWtfW2@vr61phrVPUCpU1XV9d65byeX1VzXdbFbVSvDdPoWygoBe89ckeBTwATRcUCKw4AY@JzskzD5LnDesUCoXVdrm7Xix0yvlSp7WeL1c6LXVNa63r@W6pqBbUTrugVmVctO8Cz@oB@aCMa4GgLIMUFQKTETm0hwmOpkvlFLpgfytFZHgDOQWOaowIKGHAUEyAo6FY@K@ifx9nvAP5mV59TwFYIUCc@M46Lem5jp7@lPfEZDAwaMG154UvjiQw36r5O0R@g5PmoXLcqir5X3vd7oR3gbyvFBxAzcC7SN58ynxysloUdiZoLrCPr0T4@FT7XHwzQXOBfXxljg@n6OejmwqZB@ojWyVkOKU/F9dUwBxAH9MaYQovAwjCKhS2aA2ASGtu8MJIPu51wo1z/QEqmvkXXhKwwNtBNZtas983AmDpEwoCpQ@GYXU1iFz2I9tTUW0j8PbBebUWzCYoO8NQP5E@4SA/Eq9BuVIgTJMFXoGOPRiHutJtgZe9b4g@GiLuIu8LNPeNKo8zEcgpn68JaL7h80pNsSQAezpnHqcgMx/YoOkcGDjD0p3gJhHfVnIeiUqDz6TJLwgpBBNaTLmePxMXDSPijNKwrmwycfiuZj6rlhGLj6J/Zc7G7IJSSD8ToDOZmg3hkka/1aWfOQAoHk3bUCmADNRCSAOhSMsd0wNN1fNyMGl0n0i@pXeHoK/mWoaF7gfAlPUKQXZbLWMRKNQELrGQzzlgVXY8bI1ZIVvKqtJAgZNcMJ5xi/np/iEBtjRStydnathE5XtDx4NY4vmff9iBRphtop42Jq3ddzQt/Yboo7uwxURUfKGf@a0byGdUMeR6CGVbw8lxzfQd81FT6ytKT3P6qByL5gYCxR@ghHtojeecW83kc34iVUaVPDkjxCyjz9pzoAl2avKKJ0bmENPWOlQN3Ghh6BTJwcbmzaCPuPoeEk2BxSxKaM4cEwsWdXi9oTfkv7iO46FmNAb4va@LFoXcB3qM1jL0e9rb0a6GHVsBcZxKi3lanQMbFJwsqkrX1K64s4nO@SXnZXOMy0sQs8RzEdhNDxRQshzkbujxEEm41tAdKC1oJw/6DL1RL@jfk4Jj8t9FIIZYEuk7FteaYdLPI9rbpyuiFJB0qaJxzZYSqjRjqppNrTVGe0rv4wkMEyR5ENhNvZ1O54s4gvoT9IGJdjBYHB@HXYq/vj4/Nl8txqtkng6c46vEFG7lpzKLdWMPNCyMWUZfM5VCJ@RcyMylfT9wzQEl45rSNjUXSMsTzaFfQ/PRz33kjoNSG3RjJ3DdQ@xBduQ6jUVT/oJjiQ7dtk3DxV5tLmKe07OkQZq4Xo9@QvMGxryK7ZCI6fYU3zWfL9htD@fbFxDaIxgcn@rGxQQhysnaiyqtbd/gd6FU0bOvdf47f4x7NzdXj@BYikkkYbTnDiad9kOUimu26Gd@PV7NzZfXNuf6T/YBaYcK662PpGvXMG2XndDvfdUCYrTr8t/5FB2uQUOzFJq0C7vnRxOZGrCsMIUvaFfNvLTN1cplToOfhY0/dLo4JojnY7mfz71U9WHuJUUj21LFcyHbv8o5Vw@1Hc0fObiyIuS8ZwSex8LEzPHiAoISgcul5hduL1@hmNkcNy8sagCn3bvRxvL5HUaWRbUrR5bBmERtkPwwwnoFHJ7Dxe/vklrp/tQ6j2NPM2jXHipEqHGvTB0GMvqdaVJWyKsfGUPN5x/PrLrmUB/qc3nVYeuNjmvk71FAHp@pvCjGijBJo6EMDdI@1DuhOj4q1ziG49u9DEYzDejkD0o6c/ndAMTzAWrbR@A4QsdsxEtrOJho3AkFzjq@v@Z6A9mz7c5EJjHkYzlS5WF5akLad3X63qtXcT0QJyDrxXw@L@Sb0CTDxMt9@lbRj/vG4L8TCZNPkPKElWQOzsCiDE1tXLkK2nYfx40Ki5R/Al5fz1mGpXtj/F3UBPO4a8u2zY9pMmCyHQPlNZBCcTbuoaabkYXEEj0WmDlcNJK0uosMHHwAEooo1B7q2Pe1ftgC/ahmVXAdAfTKy6nX@00@IXv2Q6nAsE52JL6exVwsaArjiZqtZNfu7YFcfLVbuqnxx2i1dB@@9WzxXny@iCLkYppwxElKPi0ZTHPHpvjUYAyVZXRAqenpfZ1e79EGtM6boSsfC4FGNn7nBGdpEnhRvIEBjMHC34kp0JDo5NkWqGGe5lzqqMeYuFRB@C5ixnLSYW7l7ve1S53vk7uPWwZWDVzPzbW/wDnfvlHlSwHbEI2vx7mfFKAzXeljVz7nInw@bkN7DvsPW@Wm@n2bVo891NGzublzLQ/IhlbP7lk9vceXZ/lvi7oHUKTHdzjeVwjIv1j6xYhHhZePhWvXtE3zMbWLPJJzTNvuzs3XLm4@60DUj8I71loQIB4PWvxgfKdKooF@Ud/p6UMYplzbswe6Qm@LQE00EPHfRZxUzn99V8vTvVYBqBH5/K74H9RHLzXbGwzo0RyYQ5d@KKpCewbnNeUeJfMYqjA8vh6M065@abfaPeOhLLV0zbOMq5y0AvHXe7XZQagWDKbsoHfWNKDynHEWqaEeDj/Bx/6iJg3N8Mwt/fbQccYPc4jJZS2@zZZPNaBjUfpi6nROMMkDuOBRLuy7Z75DzLQuJC8Su1HEVvQ8iCzqQhvSxKpbwcZoym@BRDRVbspMaJrtY4yfYhUKmQGNkI0W/CeoZmI2fu4wZfWGl@4sk@NW@Q4IV/gzt7W3LnFfsMs822auad@EjNQw9miWeMwdiv0JyPvmTcr3Tpxkc2LaU9GHC21hpjFw@S9TuoW5WGan0WehxvN1YdEUHb3L5zbQ9ZA417cd3L4FcoPSdnS3jfZxZLlcSOLsxbIvgfUqJguAJezcIszO3M9v6fCwpnz5Qr/UcHHrgYHrXM05RACYpyfxH4P4@0PNNb4/tD19Ls7pyfzHoHyuXRrtzyZaQSKUtStWQvLHBLWj12xD3PQMl3bRSMf8HsLJjCbm52hkUyZ4fzf3/aaSkDAkFt0zZZ/Jxfm@AycBMFybm9akqCnm5BcyNcMj86p4zi3n/IUP99kZbob9wdAVj/mp0xqksJ25f0X@7o0BHE95CwyW9TTTm2@LDplXQYgSo17gXCRa/8Aw7Uv2g0qegcwFIxFK2gsI6xmMwUeaBz3AmkOslP4jJzvReqE4vHBvgRD0IlMMy/Dut9R4ngbKj3xigbh8hXs@cwf4m336sRiU0/m1cnDv0AzD97htgjrzENTRVw9A6NsPyz8PTNJUcWC0raGn4NaJ@waJ1XsHiSobVVZDVMAS3999/jIpieGy1@Zrih@SIXVQ5IauOQ5cC9cIzKExwwJhazGbnY0hNYIdvasNTe@YVsE@It7WALenEVffsedpLkdjGGQ@Sv2BcWLY39HbOHP4qDy8sJ@DMAYj1wD4av9Yxxn/KVayODJGPbDbmgl11nlUcieEfs6wECjO2kBvQdubgWu@tLUI@Y7maQskJDIEknbnux6kJcNs6c4bNPOF3YuU1tlMfaaPSM1YTFBc9lG8dpuL1Gh6m@hHIc27yk4GNt@2fg9N@NwGxgj6efzceRaXi0@MeXNVr9lyHl7zdSN6h@@VdOcR9LHess2H2Y1l8IUCmmPobu7AsIYj8mMKiGzzlRm@bjqfXUMThtuDDnhjgO7sL6fGNWd8bbYb6ARiFY91rbk0fT9fW5lYuv34xUE9zWnbOA8mHB85Cxbag3e/chGsTefLDFpAPiNgdlp7KA9yeCCrZr/Vp5/FWsdkW0Mz4j7HFm3a9bTRPLlxcr@e8JzaMYe@YtsCnbDi78V3M2JDDfgZjti062blaTsx2nxERZPL4FkMzwsYop7l2U6WEVwioaXTyWSER8LZ7ksLwCQUnXeCZyHwo1RcBkOcR7BGl52dsZXbUTVfVe9YnUWrUXZxwbHih3bm744GdFjJMY9@tqJd1FfiihJfiZ9bVZaP@@C6CVLcXHBtArZr0IPnN6gCZml8ixm6ZYlr/KwHqFI8R6WnWR1TZy8tmpKA8djhJxbw4zBOcVXdX/5JRxwvc6lDYfsGaFJQIXi6kt3Xe/bNJk9XpA6jk4bH0yAOELpNfliCsr3FQBr02j1@qox9w17unVbEWRXiKCd4OeLqsp8L3rhorcd9dx5vPJ4bfw@VSNiPJQsFssewb0GH7ng9N8tODNpSN3SCZenifC/Lc9Ac18mwfdbRcRUT7ZQkC7Rp21e0ewJz8pd/wk/ooP2SYh@bTJ5O5gmliNsiVToWo922h5BrieSd7tgCJIGVDCL4EOd7GEpl5J/EXYR0dAhQpCIPzqBk@OkZ21snTNllcTylCje614xuYmXr@NMvzvIX9W9YP6f/5x/mkrei4qKfKOurbjTDJEjtDgkrHFyG4CA0zqIroyhP0N9MagiJ4oa3B1SRxokM95NKGrPtgeg1dPgRnfXjU6PYQ59AN7WzPEGjT@cmEcHqN3SCBu1aslCewAOJLBc6GLwmCTXvdfWVxJBPQSgnHitDgngKiQYuftISba/E0yAwysqIvWc9JDIYldRyHt54RZp4AEm//kwuby2Glx3ndvTWkNbfXReyhWKdirPSrG80yAUDno0HAZ19fT4q5JXz0druRc6VlXp@PvokX/gSat12INaTHPa83Rc7tyvZRv79e1cbs2j0Ll7jy6SBTazcHu0f7Z6cbp2@PIFWuJPsZ49vJJG8BqmIdqr1bJOOWIJ6weHuI/iP/4YHHiTYisY28Py/ZDIS3lNEoKKuo0p0hTtDrGki9gPR58V39VD4LIDgaV2DSYrah4Ef2xCIDWsNCz8c4EFRTMQVh90QlRnI47ED@RWDi9Hn8FKqqiirQ2UpUFmPrCq2uLCb3O8xNfYglvurbXMuCNaYn96ZH86LOLcK7n4t5R7AQPmrl5tjub/cBHNPuQHU95Vx9rb2D14e705GAxqjJ3Hd@npZbKbjzBl7Gl@4IE/3oT3sIiJO39SjLEoR@KsYzIa4q7Wlezc6FEswx3afRyYKpfxHIwFhQs3U8YTMixqvi0SCcoAySA2LNbXXr2uMQlmUY3QI3S0vos8E9qI@apnxbFRgjtFRh1n8yGIgVlFdsusdERMX/DruhsWfjOxxWDQco4cu73MLhip/1HEZ/IdGJekqXLARE8OZesEUVoCvqVuXUGAJm6zxMYqt8IqIrvC8R/384jF7kKfOG40MqrQ8WuxKg1Ha1AZ4ppeAfmF7epW9Hdq0D18yE1@@uEFzncZPlKSmbWtYGtrfD2Is6CNy3CJ8@3sndZTOuGhG/D1Mc0MLByoACp3vuIsb/oDY@KZBflIcr3JbHEomh0rSTlxxCJEvJbjs2nANkKupEboo45jAKbE0ouB4PiqdwMC2TBdkkg4M3yCheDjUgnCSpe06fM@OYrFoDGgy64uMGRaNIKxbnz2kCobSG9Ac2q955BWCI8xuCGd8Y1lRoOYuQZ0SW3@qeDwozZZUmecMcUlOIz4TRWahSi6l5/XNEOCc4/rO9dyH3/kDfkTfuQfunwj3KP8M3n5LvHXB/dsyRFXh7Z/7bwV4@yl/@zqHTTZ7LplIXmj8C/c2AV0@jc6UCXmCPBKVyuK3Nrb0F/tHzAVZlrdlH7SkoJmQwyDNgWYL9NcHorimNkZwnkLQhAGexNkXQCJAV0AfKN6gREPp6c5FAk@nquZymHE0uWZpWZQ@4tOWdFjV2yEe0ghCWG61vFpSc5BJ5VoipPMzLnGDBkeYTFaBJ0aujUH9NWiUGxsbLOq2NVOvr9Y4beRWtK@L0dd@RlcANsIVhTMGcSBKEAPCGiJaYkVLq0mMigNZXI0jT@vYnNRAGkyQA0CS6G3JHfcgbtqiqoCOLX3kkcQ0lgoQMGyLtpTq/KhOiUgBRBw3HiU43R2DnRdoIAh10Gy4GaKvEOwEwarRecR69jU7986tC3GkJAPC@8Uc0rXA/c/mnDPJKQtPFJk94DAxfTwhloY9PbFstLLsQW5ZopArFHPqajJEoVGBCvKLXf09oITODcyirRtv7IG7tb27//nh0cnMQTcEGZ8Gi7N4YyN9rmQzZxe@I@7ne7JSn@3lTp4/25NVGc5VYOlAiGBZ2nQ256U2ndMFqb/im1xm06aAmYTU/GMR03oPZY@Wc85iD0JzIcBtvsZ@JtVE8vbu7GKjcW7FZpJ/P@/w0lg2hcQFrnOXji6NT2cTs@gfa36Kx5q7Wbl5U8Wdm7ivx7Ovgn2lwiMUwMElFuAAkWxOQs2hWJmBQ26fCY6WKPBz1V1ifdyGQ0dK@jkKQZ7KE9ixawUnoYkjwHqa2zONVgTG7g4ei8cP8JAnVPhHf2TdgWl4iWSErB91lICAiSXEOeyj6ihLczQJOsCUcGXYfaeKSXzJCHQCwBc/Gro9dmQPWGB62tGl6xgEEbYz5NZ8nX0@7ANclx7HOrJYHUQTBSJDRcX9rHKFGnqWOFRslMaD2yC9MzxaTBQ82@@UE6NktqePOsYlMPBEMgM9/RMVJCp/My0Wmg4as@LA43gNf4p7G8JV@lFny40C5NqZljWsjj5K4GEp1QsQTdE/fvPqOp6MztAAHXC3LY/EmjrpTnZEzRM9Ijglbqqzra/7nWzyKML1dTxwBvcFQ7NAiieecwBOGJ8S3b42YIkhHcHosiyj18R5wsq4npNkSoOfm2CxdJoUanhQAAjMCNolFxEOS@CJxYlcHVoHfV2rg493xoCdqdnsBbgpkSRbQWPaNgzlaIZKRkBBgihVQlvHtmVVzBGn3iynPIiD4RE6E4rhOYRzgunkQJzwgn4KdUGlZo0nobN0gh7Ia3V9vSpaY5LVrDMgi1kun80B2jksRAqoUL9imyfUGp6sDVDbjt4xgC08/Z5uWTpUENBMX4MxWBsCkTnJjLx4IROcxEwpxHgWPxP7RiGjkyc078ZvTZxHWsnVyC5Tu4Mx9fU5DqpdMayOc/91Lpur3SZWzPo4B4JOspFY6dXVdDGVTq9YqcSKhUP9kydozrlbAUmimQXtaARAyoqZrAE9g@RRX7FqK9pGYqVTL6QoBryCfnYLEb5xc9nbFe0ut/IERuoM@Di88yZWXDrkL5/NqneQP@whK7kM0MwtnolGVzBg8itGOo15yK40MQPf5M5P0sSzz09yZDmqCUE0d9kX3W2Kq/otMXPnBK9A4S0aGhh7ARm7WMPblMDB@czFeWELZA@e8PdwWwSjdVm6G5b8o5Mhj2csgt/F6fwlfqQiP2URKnCUgErE14yWTAIz@du/jamrLJpY2Vwt2ul4OV@DH7VWZmX2ycp5oRRjsaegqedSUSd6e76jXDO9W1h9q5xp3ezbi6Oro6Mvk@cJFo9tH34dVUsAusbW6fvYzxorLPiwj/vEYqlcJJZLqU/WcrnXr1@DuAufs0a2EYbKXiTPlPjFWWINXhpra6nMaiWVeRpvYk6SiUIhecKYYeTYuTFwOx342j26@yQR4x@2uYlpgQP@mfDrj7rcL8gMBxG@Mq4MegjuWivH2PmapqXSpcJTq5Yt5At/@WfLd5nbo@bGX/5GP6cv4@MQHz@5e47uE7X8yfLyJ8@elUoZqDzuPvrB0VdbW1ulnUz56Ky8WVLyyxt/8R@XlwuFjUJu@cJ11Yv42dWX0UK@FM3@5R/Fj46@33RdbD/8FJkKTvytwFdl5TK7Yu/gc9Vl@E/ud52QW0N3q/sOB0gQluvEbOLxcjF@8nUci/supqpqbEx/TaqGZaY2Ntf@y88O38a8WKOQe@XA04u9ja1WYtwJDngryrfrWCO2gWCrd7Fxrl6vg3Ptv/w7iN/4HPBgyHgDfhpliWt1HGsodYryPtZYBYdaKEC6/@cPfxiJNUZICI39PVZoFFKcVtTKE/WJ30bnMbVSOnwK3vJD3iP5IUVXVQvnsj1DzY1N63v3oPDQrswO@fntLikjxgQ1kOOxcJDv2C5@/up//6uf/9XP6O/n9P0PeM3I6vLT1zuM6TAC46dafeqXLsfWKlHbhl5eg7cD3/84q8An25TvNXxVRMlilXqmyXPlk3As5JiqB/@XiSrx3z8SLhKTM6zKGbsINUG0gfxJ5vW5xZ7zj2XBP3zlK/qgB7gsFmRa1m0sqFI/cTbtJxvDf2GSF7CPgYvEvoHKH835sEbgz6gIPNfkeB4qWVA2JIdN@CzDH/3Dx3/F32XyEd4EMvtZZt/9E4mdxc4uLj6z8K/1Fv8O3uHfWw//Ttv4d/wW/07f4d@xh39HLv49b@FfmJcD0QJnSKePQWQURPuYz0v4ZrNN8eYTbywS@7V@WITFlIu0cnd3lv16lK7VxD/IUTX/DT/cBTm6uFOUja8b6fQZ5eysIbK4oVw0IJs8t/Tz9QYgTm@cbdTtbfpmmw34KPGSHV@1n1583TjbmMQh0Dx9msYu@xTwNFYuGEjwjQa727hr3J1t3N1tbMD/Bv3eiSf43m3M/NMj@CyACcIvkHuen@Ua57nzBv9cwHs210CfbO4cHA14NgHw7CwSu0VaqbOzCzpqqK6cqavlC4VRh0hhWNtlrKqmCsVcefTJ6m4hEitEozkKeo@jEsgW65EYSujrXFBfJ4/XH779X/F7/uHbfwOvkDW8tgtDkZYYSDgrm3kzf51Xr9QrcBgsDwJmL99TO8jR8zrLj/Njlu/bagdcOvzlwWXkuyx/yfJW3lJVCASHx/IeurrwuIS/LmBx4M/I5xF5/ppBKiaOE3QmKj3fN1nyPHLGoq91EE2yajybj2dX43Hjorw6eBvNxJvnZ/GLWiznnp/nuNDGCqUaHYZ7d8eazd0XO81mDun4/Ll9GPwfHvbDr/f@9w/t54d234b/w8PD59Bw6adp5Sl86o30hnhsxhq1zfOqguTIe1K2GcttbJ43igq6V9NAZAX0S3/kJ8AIz8byeQQ02levbmqvXuH/zXXtpkYO/xUczZoPIMC4Azy5ByB4VauRA93wuSas9IbOm1fnvos7cq9uwOsVAxnb/89NvP0a/o3/d/0/f8kSZxdJ6Ae3dxsJ@iTxL5m8vbu9E7@NZCIhXhIb8Ice8I5Rbu8a6CSgW3CdJZIXybs77ge/ieQGR9jANDYaFDkAhE4f46mex0HMAK0wIWazzs9H@Xyy1gIf366tvaeJkWSNloystHAyCzQhNZUkkHKpVisJ91qlVqsIt7q6WqulfKg8vAgnAOmu1q5hb6rFBknMA@9jiTwazOjA@XhC3E6wORiAVquu59@/972azY7hNJvoX3z//hy6axxXjNTXy@CTr7x/D508ngSN94Ut5irXQX9Vc4UAfU9zNc9zEu@MQeY8josT3fN4kk6EzecRGOOz8sbGaqnRWC2Be7WSTNaiK3y5SeIyva4m71ZyUV4M0EXjMRGkVtaS5HsXx3AW22CbDSB3Fz/s9i5Gtc1K5WSiNdaTvoe6vs59WGk1UUmvi7/6cpI1Ukz8nZ2dFdOl1Frq6cXFxZSkgvyodqvV1bv6rVZFK8ldrS1OFsc15tqTJ8V1qJxKvnYeaTZ3tk63mngpGU7/IltGT@JsEZzaGzjxMzJpldcvzrA4F@fxeLX2lLdupcxi8ZqAU@LAJFllnUodA73Z6OLmkhFhnfqmYgOmrhVjqciAVuGs5VkHJzIdZne7y@AJLcNaOOfs6qYpT2K/sR2zc2N09OVI7Ohga3v3NFPYgHGqsLe1nSmcvHwWU/G1HLxTcBHfj3e3dg5fQoSjg92tk91P97/YfXkE/m7kzTtN1zV9qOs3zeHw5i0e1q039QH4Bp@m3jZc7c0bbUAfVuMs7ebmwy9@/OEX/82HP/zphz/88Yc//Pkvv/35j@H7J/D9KX/@9N@ul/H3l9/@8z/@8K/@EDz/A3z/PXz/7Jff/t4P@Zfe/xy@/ynk9@fiG4LjXxZrpPADZFApVNIpGDJS6@tACuS7EYGkfuuX3/7sj3757W//Pnz/pfj@/uz3d/5s/vfnP1r8xXg/@@P7YX767@D7v3BcEvan/4r74XMG/l9xuN/@/Q@/@7/x/78Qf@j8ww@/@@f4I17@u9//i//04Tf@j0Kh8hf/@sOPf/rhRz/78KPf@PCjn3z40T8tfPi9f63mwz9/DAT3N3/6C/z/2Z/@zb//Bf7/z//j3/zpf/83v/U/keMPuOP/@pf/lv/@9W/8@K9/9C/@@je@XfD743t/v32E/7d/Bz6Pz@dj8DymXB/r8@13ys@vUhtBKkADdMA5K4AE92ysg2IdybO8@IEO8/N/9uH3fhPo8HcBEt7@W3iDf/4CQT@hly@/nAhLk/qtpL/8EoTZL4Ve82UY6CeMvc@BtJl/@h4AvqRQ/mE@FCT6PyAUgDEBJcEmEicQXOzHvX/57b/4I/T3Y6Lvb4bx5aVvCHYFgd/LIv4EO55fjDDsT7DrfvjFDz/80T/98Is/@PCL30KurZTWM1sZRX3A5geA5UfAIeDqY@AAUEW1BpTP5UgBHMsbaKOKqOnXr6ERlsFVZywVKRfhLaI2yK2iGyKCqpripqE0GoXgO4qU1uENjUVpGC7TPCgNQc/SeA9uOjKqQxiB4gW6DJ2NCmr/qBPWAS9G4nEyzQoI6Gz0jLBAzHr6mDVT9RGPmEaPBmFgmCH0Oo6qhWi6Ut@BBOujHYa4EHk68hqer@uNSn3UQHTfUBYAR/oZJAlQeD9vetT4Bt7rhBPgI6OdbyArlXo63aiAT52KSqllmpSmWqbCUdnTjMqN/ozhgrvNp4x9ElUrUa6WQ1UyAY2/6QB6k6xTmxB@nk6J4tC/dNI3hfGhnUZUP9yPh2@iN8UXAIBXUXCdFnwVBXPzFIJHHFWakoVHmmOAmksLu57vQaJEOpKm9k3TC6QPefiYzwYfSBEdFmdlZQVcG41oMdo8BL2IOVdV19McnEoisa7KoqvrUfTGdS98Md/KEalPqZ0U/Krwv7tMC1ipJLVUZCWOWnWcyZSUdNEu2TFeCFlCektRAdIEyD6BEPw@fQpuqCF6Bn6RWBCPC@40awgSd4klIwm6sSVJuruO8gqLPHcvn9kjkK4z0WhGXeWzAUmu20e@sqvV@jdqaS0CT3of4m0x4t4SaC68Mze7sYHV3rhVuJ0B3SDFrUYaDTHzyVTwYbVI42T3FCKdHjK1kM9GGl@yUZbslXcMWh2k9NvSWqFULpULxdXV8lpBLa2ul1bLlSJwuNV8uVBQ10ul9cr62h3l8ikwiUw11SpvNP7JzOe/@ifzPvN98RNpmHW@AG8FZ0Kj5/lojcweVIkrZ/kM/hWKRfiFfGXU8trF8rJ5q2DZz2nV1y3ONUPWIrcKUvkSfFhkKcKWwAs@yl0E54KYmL3fP6yJmVq8@Y3P1kbVMpBRMnIOZMSxifZsNED2Vvb3IoeHh7TukM9EKkYn28vS9WydoaNHCkXqSDv7X@yf7B@@yO7sn4BA/BUrFKG6h8Mhmp@F/TwyCH9q8I0gpTwBLvhE5c7yauDMo/MUt8C@gMxDs1vsANd6ejY7tfmawmd6O7IhNm82IjRldgYNdhHBe3XOcPFtZCPnh8/Htd3jV0BvOzZoCt8d5plmXfGgHYNv2/ODPtPw7D23b3i9BRAvB33cf6U7f2cYdvstyCBaxznAM/hxTNueB7DGXh4tKOVzf1M9Tj/TrnoAP97/9LPT0PN0d2v7s8gqe3b4YmfqURZAZXawu3fqv67xUBm17KP4avfgYPpVPGLYwVHlW2bltUwG2Df84DNDH3pmV76WIGr2nptLVnIweoK2Xle/UTYalZq30mUv68@@Sb8Y9kuV4rq6Xm7sMih4zQENzehc6qDP2j28BtKJaZ525Ky4bFVlpTXUcI8OQMVt1huaeXvHio3Ic1wHt67y/RyGG/kMFM0@Xj@DV015Edzj18ErZtE80MK7XocDttATHuiFTse47AGrvbElQKSlaQy@H/uB@GEdEyrsXg@Pp0F@MyHmHHCcfDW6LB/Jku2ysF4pV9aLhUqmsl4pldXVcjmjFjLqWmVtHXhdXq2oq5XyupqplNaLJWDAEFpeX4vEgEkZ3VwOxhw1GqWnYbXxGO4NPM/czvYakRi3yjD2Di8xj2m@x5BFdYgTxbt7XI9W@aaMerRQwiX4wMUAo8baLLa3t53f24tGn@EL2mi389FoB1/KlXx@7Vk0qlPINgwShWjU5nEgCMA8/pLPP9uORoccAZ4KEI328GV3FYXhaNTAl@2tvT1M5w2@FDA@gF3xEP5iypc1ALPwpVgkaToafeujA7gtnlCJcrqLL5gmhuzxkG0Ii0Y/lfnJ5wHDMYfjGD6TZd3aikb3@cvWFoZ8TgUv86x@D1@26BONOvACRBiNXoLj0tF1KxptgRNJMRptg6s91sAPzzzH7eOWp0WjY15BWEXR6IigtfZVFKQ@4Y/JfPbZZ1rP6@iX/DN2@LMNWYMQYzTc3Wt9@mnr8rLljLd2Pz3GkM8//0x7Mx46rcuWiNZqwseGOBBy1R9PfyCP@82mZs4N@R6EWFMhzXFTx7w1tbeQJ/G5xET6zc8h5HMImTdhx7HBpw@gLfw868PzmdaiEPmhEHqOWq1oDQnVGw90NFxhn6E7qDN9re3YNXwf1ZfjiXhmfLaav6iRN@snkrf52h2GdhN0/xnyRJa8HZ@N6vkLUAXWCnKfQCJ6PiqUjWhmub8JvK26rG2qhVJ6VMWTG@1unMUVdTOhPkm9S7xIbhaKpWr0fHNTiZ6pF5sFtVJdXfs6NYxGk1X83SyuVd@BPBfPM0Y/ybO1i821cijO2lpayxWqa2ssWbuD6vBgdGoNPb3ZTCRudO0qmcQMk3TCoBj8xu0xldSodROjzKjOc8bGydqorgIb9oYwLuVnsHVw0/wQb/fhOC8B3WgzX0XbYSKqrleikINcLoksCZkIPF@/kpMC/iPkmHDyT5ZVFX5NGVMrqyyZxcXnTbvbpGtT2OswLMqnkVe4SYQ2iMoFXSTMu9XIKcqzdLU5w3M5Wng3Iu3CBoWKHxDEuL1AXVuPRBpCkjvilw/UxCtuss/u4SW4tpPFyxu9iRC@BVx6nYxBTOhn9w@zLy1X6/pITvWRl/1MxwVbbem3zTdxZndHePm3YVu1W@WVckd7xXHbJx45YHSYVm@AS@skKG2mJW@oVM1Go96s9/X@wBuD3kA10fDjwsjKnjEOiRtI5Br6Zv0ZFDZfs/CIHR1fV0axUaTRwZMEntWf3Q6rVYC9q@l1utw3GovWuptWfUilOdId3O6xfwgDuI77Ktq91@e7CLcN9Xp7pzQcZtX8TOy7vHL8FfyUn1vMjwho1vN3tcv6Gfq/x58NJRq9AN3h/UWkAf2qNo5pdXfY4ndL5VugZ6zWRuCnrpVqPdaqt74e1Zz6AITlmgk1FZL4mVYj8PcmDJFNEBhGQaGL9bNCsYCLdTKF/HqmoMK4COMlQMN3Dd5L8FXhC@Eq6gUJMxFlLJrJj/JZNaPqasazdy2o43y1ilUNbUSv8NSS6ULKTHRspm0o1GTQRWuYQ2AZPTYwMr0ExDrWNZODg/rGlITydnM1XSolk7W3kEFnJdHJPktulmqdxDPWTIIHDPDwLbDVUi3cyolkrVtPfJ2sJZaTdVd/G2lgP6dCD5aheoW@4w77Z/nlVTVzqzSVO1NzvRV1rVA9G66cKSoUMP/@ciP6g0b0Air/LsIiLDyXAKJDDfxkj@bCRiAuBH4DFBlNHZpKXS/UBEhkILgLVGEC7zrlywET8fhaIR5PxmsAtQzemG9gJ8RK4sDa4k/UzSiIK9FqdL0A4QFTmskBn1FaVSOxu0jHcAestB6J3Ububu82wkvQvsfGYy2tyNcnjF2mVyIsR9Oj2WaMLZNLyTbIDLJV37o83qoJ6K1trrvlQisv2LnYOKnklj92Tja90fiaP89xOQGkCqJqyzbP2IWYhC4Uocyd0DuUz72N8Erl0@y5jXQjdx6JRrGfipm1RKWcFGrmNzE6Q5lt38pLvKvP@SigVXkPPLtIfvPCMG8rRaXBV0Wy2DdpqBJcgdTIfRMD@rq7o6oW638iMcuWS4FAl/SAsQHnL5ejaGTQ2eBk/eu1rytfP395@PJwjz3NVyvVSlgdOH@ayahxNb7BnoLcaRzvQl7fM7usfmN9TqudYrVYdRAvluLFiWj12Khe8suoNhqKulFgm0CcrAoMpquuKvn3DU5pDQpYLUDIh9/8/dJoowLvBZDtqlCL5XSh0VBTBZaMffj23@Cm5sKadKmra7GLGE@itJYEN82AFdRYIye81TU1GXMV/gapl2Pu@1ghX4ltH4qJzegqVEZsPRaJVZ6/fs/YBqhyjc7lpVEgVy43oR6tVEEpgn/2DdpbvlGWXwNTcN2VHK7EWUdgaSxINRqNFC3QiTfSuMGrUCbr9Nld7YKr/agPpCz6090U/ulf@x4p14V3@QavqQ2dlRsqAwUil/vwm79XKKz@3//xd86T75vvm98H3ri@vr6qFmJ/O/vJpZYiLLW0xeL8VEE@7OLhwv7mt/jElado8UotKTsnh9vf2z3FcVe38EwNtn34IotBJwO9HexebJu65phjvmmwO0YoHK5Pt4@Y7bCXO0cU5xXtWyVfsluJVFb2O1Vxt1nmmqnZIs7ylnP5Uk4tg0RRza9VC6tMAzbl4jkVwrWCURkVa9sejLnyl9hOUuSlLYTBsAMDtHJXr7JPjw4oBrGB1NLO7vNDdvji4Kus9OX@p5/tn7CTw73TV1vHu1CO57snLLp1wvZPouzV/ulnhy9P2daLrxgEH2@9ON3fPUEEuQiyOJROeYX5mhjbcMduDkVXl9SxCW/Xbl/p3qS/5gy0HJ6gPelt4d1bOl5VM@k/tAzQ9cKa3snWEhf5GKLXOh0nghtmjTZbQiVvKQViAu7X7eXdNVYefvku75SXWbv0Ir7G2vkXVnFjjZl58cfMUr94zJaXl8@tqD8@hIvhK5phL9wbAn5BnvZ/sLuUWC2xFGiXhVIyCHlxeLSUl29Lr45Pl1Q/7HhnqeC/7O8tFf2XXXgr@W97r3aWyv7bs63vLa0G0V5sL635bzu720sV/w2IdGk9wPliZ0nNR2RlXYMkt0R33yb29g92WQqAkrWJUDQbomPKGyoiAdIXP70Eq5ylUjc9O0OKS2s8Bd3RH4KW4BNQSyj/nWG9XmRYyh7AD0iWAAzRaAMKV3mcy3ZGYMVD5mDwiNxGlrBAS1gggF/CffMIx5brrJBkELzU5WpRgh8wmmHRly7tjv3EZRso0zeAGDJ0ah3tkoYYuri5O7J0J1AmumRa7dLqewJVIadRJwriU73OXrw8OOCJDUhsTUQJknEZdg5OewDYoIjwi0UHX944vFmoLbCuloTQgbeLR@4mWjMy3ZpYFVDOpaU2IJis3WvNzDAUujK4DALx4gvfNQPAEAzuPLj4ntJEoo1lvdS9NmUoiZW5e7jHS4gLKepsspWTDBOlmqJgvh/n/Xsm3869yVdn8tWKc9wCOc8Wx8dzWkfYJPotyc28BEEHF1DMJaSYdBpiQ3EoLFSuJah0@PJzDmQuG5BQPs6ePKF8bMDbepySwHhpSpEpCIIIRIVR9SEyP2vLlN3kUi5F28Nw3RIdgozjCD@8ujX2z2gBzjqd0alW9Xuh35xLFii9tSmGLIK6HWxrcBcLTXhH9giUnGEt6CYZJgPVVQxEnS/D9AzrgvcUT20aFlCu7gQ8UZICdEZq/Rc7vIX4gUTkzz2oxMD3qtRgwCyeYPclQl9aajmg/tckFPBDggK6RaJJYEVwuPvjHe9QtBTvL0iWGPsxMff3qpKOeGwgB0FpVK14hgSnFVFc8mwEQDP4BTLsv3VAz0mSI0unBYRPZQJsdxJOUTjcnaTLBwqxO12K5Y8uBbLlhaXYfWQxfrVSwLAWkAiUAlh8AvCmAZp@JluzMA8FjIWEgkrz3VDAABrQEvTxCQSPiA9DbhBf@fj4MEhXp7sy9FtoQc4VeJTJ1/bka2fyFbsv@GhsY4MVSqDKtNClroILzxJgFXB0OK@cjNidfCWTUJ3pMk7X58A8BaA5ZJUcDAlwlhkjB8m6eCuP1sd74upsa6@5/2L3dDIU8WXdpsh4z7Mtk9JIToKJDGG4m8CXpJ@jRBcrgcubiSOeRobqs3lyery79TwD@UuyjaAHTMsA8CN6wkQJ7mQK4GvpbRiPOxmWONliqSR7gjnLMGFLwJdHJ2Harg6oFqbYGQ4KlFSeg/jvkz0phj0yMiepaIIlkuz9@TkMqfk1pvYH74v9orVW7LBxcQ2FXY7Hl0EEl5cM5gXvmlzYQMgOP161OjexN/k8KzlF5uk9kLhHeWcWP5XrDsc2Ghbl5u2BTUqZW2N4siLyFnE@DIyLk6LN/VIkjY1IB@iL3Rj8cDgnK2Ka5HMkTwqVAhbPS0f/2Lw8JNFO5kXhedmgRGfzILTXyGnYWozzhOJAjGHLNFAPpbuY2T4azcfyfKQM69vQaAa62vaAnmhtEuZxeHNtE37pQC@c2KXzrPXRwLQNPHoOj8HByXcnOHg2Gzm0WB/0XLIacxu2gafHiS3ldHIOP6SPtrRGltrtiVu4Q5dzvwYtaWBdKkDdXeOSKUq7a2qXLjjMDrleR07840MwBdPQoAYpCfWgqan5stC36ZxezBzeb3304lOGZ52ibi@NSJppeGNau4tCFq3f1fFcYNe41oHt4EFLeicb4Wrso1S7sB@apSb9aFvvlMKrua7uTGm1Ax5Rkk8u9RTXRT9N5QTd4Cbdpua0DA/vmGhyY3GTpygF@cGkQkWLOQTV4QIOTna0IZ47@9oI36ZiYY2RZSyYDkUlAVLU@rpUoVKpAaEkYZLxlxDm1GAxbqN/@etCPYG7Y@gTeG2oqyHUFfWyGUb0iUuamw8EfIc40O6X@6dNcRoX15vk/NN9amSolmvybVDjJQjlX@R8VtdEtgnZxyM9@KmaUNRrm9NylJQ51PmgteE/pELSZUqYdcQ2oCH2rHTB1aI86SOywv04TzglPAnl6klQoUtilPBp4JHxuNbJQWbLi4i7jq4TAKmo0hw@pcH8mmlvQcu0TM26QleN6/8s5TrtUGPROUOhcqAe6JdFKIV8/hHKDVF93T7IaNTxm4UAhJYvm/mlhd2ZjIgYh7ewnzSK5JiGOCOlj8e3thNBcErKEbxsSZkSh59K6hC4tt1Fc4HtjHlCeEZColYDEBQ@iCfollTBQ6WuB7WB6EhSCeUC6LYmvXDlmB7kM8Puzy1PapnIgcSa@VnlEg5CnfnZuuBJLeaFUN/JcGEmogaVI@UicMLQ7oEkbupdQXEwjBGNcJV7pla4@OpTEeP1dJa/gH@2GX6pcmsEdigdTUDIQpLYjfFkhanM@ZlG0IbfdTCpgPSoodAshU1oEC0yAyQG9GdGOj3RTiHkZwbWm8rSVNuJOaHAhvwSiaoXdU8wJOhDa3D7AutysZTXdWSqikCDQAONzDW8@tR4JCe5gST8W26QwDll8r4sKrQm32Un9N0UElSKz1XvZg2ENNGve459MzBGupkAhtnEU8YGDLyEHDYYcAdB@DIZeGNjU94Fv1peTkCsM4LLVS7YE5ZQNzYSa0qCvD6pJJN@ZxTRC6HoocjApBsNliikEkUZuYSRAWVxEkFpPoICR1BKJVSJoCAQqGXAwEUMQvIJqGREtZOIKyHEPt6LSRg8q2xO6qlCWr3Y2Kig4hrynIpcmJ/1VDFdgMgc9VJ6MoSj5QEh/4vJEgHyYiE0joRQlNJFQMGTTk8GBKlOBfiJhtMsXcwdnH5twos0PsvBh6Ljkcm6c1bB8iKlckvbgIF74DnCE4@tHNDhlYEfJ@kUkjnICNQlIbWejjNBGX54qRi0oP5qU6NiyOJLEMgGqBIkHiPD3tw31rU@frBD4C4dPMPLDOpqhlVADQGOAhyjApGBhVAdGJfNdn/gw8FQXElyMxYfwCiRFzYeRn0N0n2HxH6ZErExXn14DhXgE4dH0hjC6zcBEZoH@8/w8cXuMZoB9l98Ck24hOXIsOBXFnOZY/SLuK1Z/KYEwzMgC8DbuEIjysqbajJ99JTpC2wSuYCfxs4jUukQgvHIQjokujC8pmELbLwqJR3pHtUjna/oA1SSNdAz2I3ONBOrY8zPha/wYxhpJo9iU1WBw48oMog1hHV2erz14mTv8Pg51dxRc@vg6LMtxAwKZltzOoB@0NOwg1iWbvJB1a/PCA6/l3h9CpZJa8mDxfjFMgjLT5zllQeATQppku90jrC8nOhn4Ln3vAjEUXxoECqaHX0wBzcq5D6YKIw7ByFvRZ5rMRSKPM0bCWnAmx0JJR9tIKejurR114p7QNgenfZmcX6Sk/iegZZJp85Sz0U56pLoxeHHbBYLdPY@0pE7HKBFTO9Ew9Wvtdu6S6vKgtoHlLrZpUQEZwlVFPjML33AP7jB3R97BQ46epgG3bwv9wZi7qSwCNIjr7vvJOOGBCSORcpIt1KsJLFIpMyvApgQHY1JkXFRYjy1Nzy1N5AaZ7jszbRAZlycvZkQxOZVjyGr5w2XjaVkxsUT3z5GLdeFTu/2cOU32UI416EGw2aiFY/2eILXPZFN9kT24qAnzhfu7hfKRMVOSmRiwAnGT6EwdzpQbYkZ2waZ40n7GjrY/vzF0m/whUZKPnsjVQyCJ0ppgjgt4ST7xImhhZSBmIAb0hTAmUjuggYVH19CIGSKzE8yJGvQ1LKwChgWcItgxk2UlURJ2xWKYsgT2aoYhZ2O7OQEGQxmTmd6lgqB0JfPogamVj43yROqoJOOLa4TaqSQQGalAC6rKgpESHK7Bsk0wG6xDJQ9w5tfjMpsMUThpExmcLM@sjrhVjkrQND3oPeAr0y8NrfcoXLIGT6MnAwVLF8TZmG5TOHlESuqxWJoTcPhqxdsdTVY8oA7SVipkA/WUeCeEra6HvlOdrLAnsDpETuOaFAkK6QZVN1BFtRNEzoxf3QMHPoxb1wtHvHHuOYLVymuwbqCHYuhwWV9vBClpePFH3gxtsfUkZqNLAFTPA1dKSMHbwC8HGoO3iPFJ46Rkbv20GnrlCBFpKufHJdfN0MXrgDHp@sE3aGjcwMw@HTsNt3YgjgoHrT0sE8LfTMoMFzrDq5tMjyxemmJeI4gB84aGpwIpKdkDg1JG7wKBUugHo1GFl6NNCxj7XHTi3AVSFw5PchTLk8PVBrS5OHsmAGqXkEqVMfcHVkSFTwzzJA@nhKHhMou6QMHrH@eaXB2kOHKqdTDBRo@xsxq/sbFHGMMUVc7PAaNsMYkKirTRVJO7BEHkPM6bWmH4ED0GF3Q8ES4uDaKNYjXtRjcFs6IR5AUQaMUDSkOUp3WvpIbiih4yb@egui5Dr0PF/9SYmIW0J/zFRBI8kkOISZ8pyGwf3KIURgH5IJ31JRYbkgQiMOfxEP2TRQitXB0J4VegAi4XktiF88/n2ibXwrRRylRPs82nVMKSob68nwwXmQBhqULgUGmiB@l/DWUHOzlUTCZJwEp92SQui/zE6k9NvMiuRmgiZp4ZNb9irgTtrp5SCFy377m11KJiTMpZobahwtJ0IiCEIhmqd8LU4WoA8kVeO5aoRhcZpZxJCehELGSYZblCCjfkSrINQ6SoftmzmCxwryCckqWRZXFpBakKyJMY0BD42RZRbcIl1VRZwu7FiqsXDoxUVgRSZZzdtGaBY4uXgJGi8pwQImK5RjRTzoZ9kkHJ0OET3iMkrUxj/9NLuAIdciv60GP9Mvn55VWAvgvvK@KuUNk7WF6x3iINy87Od4RQEOAiuC2VZN3ofBYS0tCnAGhZyJeISnMzj45SxTdLvBrXAxHu4cPChJTQDGEpc6@4XhoCKIbxULAEuw98XnMQNKHxXtSwrAhKhKceaKTSurAgHRajGf1CWtwsCpkISGGsQjeGVp3cW984imzuRhjGB8m5@OQUcRwH/T/Wjgj44UZweqgOSIx1vlzRnyd192vOjMayG4DIbmB3DUowM9bIYgJ@a2cl3JAYhDIC752wPWBsGwgBG0pDKJhCy/uSwz4eo8Mg9QXwgfLJt/yCb52z8GYtKwxHI3Wz4UZEs9hIaQWDUJKzGw2qXWoRge8TSbzTQ1JhhAfOy/Gk8EZIssVFJwG5M60OlOqCXSMVm6QNa7GVzSSKIsHUpCeGl7SiA2fwsLjlGWgZw1wxYNc7UAojP7A1Pk1gupBc@twP7hUUlyqors2erlZ27nM3RhXRo4DRk7EWny81B76Oa685yHN3ZcwlOEqei/LTnS@WEEXlwe@JnVSHyZfYyRc1m8BcLcLEq@Fd/zIO6cEAjcbziwEay6/M3Vs260g9xpe2gs6Kc9AhvLuQuYvoWKGLboBpq15rj7Wcxgx1zLhp6/hDv4cqOQ5LGHu0NIPIPYJXtGYfaNda5GdUMbo1qWpVGkDTURB2xGF4K29fPUI2hA8ulelZUPbQM/VaaWEUBJoG55tmWNm4bomfrs9o5sG5NWSeDch3rEjJnVoyQO/0rGUX18lZu@KEY7i4fidzUJYORnhR9JXmbj3sAbUjLoOjz6xpmVqTQbvmJOLKLieP@nXxh0HD6/T8Jd45HKhuLb1mHUf89Z40KYGqPZFKz9yOTSPDky8l/BGo7MT2HZpLb9aZfwCVCJD7C10cUQgseujAR7sjgsDcByXcU39WjdZEZvxC8MdAuCJN4QiRWIDR7vsaxIwUawyTCa08YD064llSkGQbZuTPl0NB4xAo6arpJgaYKPr58SogpUpvMW4oCeBa8HPJms2LdsesCo4OnjvIw0GeJOHjIHHzmuZFkbQko1EK7kJzyo8Ieu0Rx/6MXb@ur8oH9cT2QY7g25@weQERbQWoVJA16/z3NdkfBw5ECw0owMDNp/VgBEhxZpCGeVWAoDGMSzB4Vxu96TJcwnSsfcP0WpDCUKPHST8ECwi34SVrC1cU5JioTUlwBJwET0SJq3rz@WkZSS@hUf0y5dncR5KVqMEdwcmIj7qpfzqkOsXunz1yQZtdGC0cZGqM4k9kCKrNXYnAXENCEo4uLJEicuVAyhhOjg3E6xIgaqPSi3sPrShDBQfgKSGQzLDcSlUDEqUJh3v/HUr08HqhZzDAv96viZrg9/o4bd/MJn1hLfmEhV8me4HuRUX4iaibT4RQ7MkYoJpIq84eAkaIerguMQQn@D0QB6T1CCsiWQ0zfgGVZ5RbnMFZoEyp0JDSoaN2CVa37n6lGFj8YqHgkT4EQD5zLiu1vxzAnRr2L9FZSTDowwHGQS@Yzpw@1oEf4VG5/DE/d4NowSxdWTkdCcdeZ1JfzRt3OYzTL2rUcptOgqTs3iQI2Zpf@5arHML8VXPQBWh/ws@TFQ/6UQzPD2cMiCHKh2Fi0yQGq9EP9ejsX2VGGXGwDpYYkSrO0nrQLcwztPrOBRECy/FPI1gMGiHbWo479jEukvIbRWsOaqDgtQc19GGxzc1oMDLuwWtikX4KgNARUFA0FCZFHYpnKoZWN8oncZwUOomw4eDKmrZMv5MOLYe4efxw/jvgp0/VA/NUaY5Tsp1KRCjOU5RFfjLU@5mikvZ@xXKO5PfqfLO1Idf3gX14Zd3tj6/U3l9i/GXVBAYYuiBOg6q7JugUeONQNKT2yk2GXrmgxFq56vp2MMBHkE3FZsO65mNbQ8GtotHRczPAU9zTiYoPOQPaW7yNKrgBgU5x81HaiUPXQ/PX3EjvIs7NsqLCXLjycR8/AJ50uS2bTFGkwdiXieLvv@qTL1DAkkxlIS9JEv0y4dJcZ7KxQkQ265ofXGdhZKq@RmngnIdjFFkv/RJxl9DOEJFp@WLkBsZBSsqyeZFGaLcgfGmo6Df/Cii1gV/nIyFtc7mxpKNiLHF6kopCRHbie5zLSmQuqOhuaYmcWcg15A84euxvr13lJYEzhuDLL3xtBylQRXb57eFb4tbdY@EdQqvxaV7wB17eNljuPodZUB@cS1G6Noo3aN0CVI9Hkc9BPLpVOWyuERQfN9@nGMvBwyU/H15XfvzI7aNgn@L7lvntoBEaJgQK6yWlqTstBSYtJeI0/vAF9zQxy0OQfLUZqEM7CA9QBaeoyUOkj8mcpqTsBzEFNWXQKKa5@GpJChZixvnsfhBtAFOwwQRUQKQGxdIWFnyQednlpNxKLeUu3B2D4BU5uU2PzeTtCdhOpMtHU19@Xsyx62I07YbyA6mjrnZ0f8O2s9Plc9eg97/AGlCopIqMwSng5KLi6NB2MG9@X08ZR2vCuaUCho4oHyBl/qa5jgzF/MN2uOod2k3oHuRqoxw6azITg/02WtcaDQ3Ns249TRoKto6gIggByRayUsUEQ9dss2ekzrqR@YKsEuiHG6m5dmw2zjLLCPP1gQeqKh3XBRZNaQVymcCtzeI7ipnCTsGXtqGJfdZr8wO2aNJW@wZbb4rY/sIs@Lob4eGw5VtzE0W2pLW/QApbPd0vOIUYPEcuQC7YlgKVJvlKXaXuW@HmoMmB9th6bgbETyejzTHYiXOtBwlGFRtApgorz4rhISAUfzE/W1TZCXtdWiqkTyPFuvgmUVxV5wkJGxGWLdh2w9aTbIM@JVvkIHh2eS8GGqI8ITU7wzrDk3kxfYgi2HICScLG35DwbK1XOc7syaKGXqZAOKMdTI0hFEsQ3F8DAkaxsVIzDnNw@DrM9CY1AJghUP7Olaofv1Kg6qcqLeJ6R3aFBTYLyCY7OcJpDdXwnRxrYWjCxUC4@STGUpkFi0NxbNYLdtSwpg52CxigEOw5GPbr/731H4MBSALeQ8wmMEAb12VV59T1oX2CT2dSomELIoCfKA/ND3N0u2ha47/rgkhskSnOAvZGbzG9PqVeJ0Ux1EN49pZDk84Yfu5Q1ruhmsTUFEH5l04qGJI9FSwGmy4vi3GWWaKbTBuRh6AhtNEiVMMOxBhODjKNQFTITA6MbT04DIBj/Z4ZfiyAWCdtF3M8rIUTy6w09rekJhoz8bFFfxC3AwudegDGwF/ahJk2FgWRG4PdIcnBtQ2todMjs@eHdq/CAwy2EBoQKJi6CP8yJuxWEj3fCABPIg7hIpfER6KA@wXMg7gwcX0fHhr6cJGgYMbn92iC14hBUoWnojb4HvgggS/c2p8Fg5tvpgk4p6Kl89G6WiYkJWMr7NPLAv9PikV/an1TyQyS1uXhOUEJdb240wCraqYNctJBdao0UKLhFHHlRobuMMC@iWAnhkXy3Wca@GrNsh2hq14AwSia067B0WC9jKQYDyH6qljdKjaQIdDs7d/PoPLAD0e4pbkArQ17Ld0vCyE6svfpknzHmgkB5BEgDpJKQdbLw3icEYa6Pkcl3qS/biT9PsWT4r0ElR@ANC3I@EIKvJE9ktRMfgerGzya6ebEK9oCilgteD7mfBU1At5yMZMUOFCHsfhq3yF2jRG9R6MycB4NrUlDA1eXmiJ043tXPGZIzS7Eef3NIPs3jgXyBcsYyRp0cNJfjcI4zMZ0jgXnNVE/RkHlp7mPWzkldTkAVM0@YYevnEqqGA@h1cLFi37q5HznLaAhbW5BSongnBlFI/LZy45Y/eJR865chsi3xuUD2/dEnVdD3cF3tbClMn3tTlmV0hXE7QhIAVFILTMOZrfhUlSpqEQGoLimec6DmU@XZdgNbHdSQn73KH6z/Mpq0/Qim418rI3cvqo1zl1BGn4i4TboaW6Kbm9ga8nm6h@LPK47p9K893qjTgGN6fW2Eis76KdViO@wmtpSv9mvMRnKJIuLY0/pnaoLvxl4oFNPkrULLoB6R3@YsACp40pLU8yxi7v@nO2qohFnvwMFxjeGZ4QI7ZvwGvYGO56SX@6XnRQ18u6HtFOaKRXOPcB@p7X7zTTtWGQ5JKaORa93qX5wo@biZE9kCcv@l1r2MWs4Ew/xAk2qMzuTlnu@iyHlubyCX9eUwRO6w6HiIP3/2RotaA8JYTvWgEo2rIiZvhFxDNpE0f0Yhl1V9jIeAlYqimSFWUQ@aFC0IT3fnD0HGlVnzr6JTyODcxRx42jvOTPfGcjO9yYeHS4/@J097h5vPvF7vHJLsWkhfz@huLhIEeWMvcGTyywBN64Gz7rLht55RgwjuOIQ4fHoQZ@0rY9j@2BuquDOn6lQUxtqEcWzrkXDhaHvXR1p8rjn3Jhnjbf00pj18AtQkNcqgTlu@EKOJ8eTrhJTvwwBuIOf1T6USKWh91FkGcCM@chyD@xJ7VsOqeVIMTOBhxS7K53gxKg0CYm55j9@7uyYo2thEaTQ3Begn8gAgoAEI6rbsdZupMi3Feh4nWQOVGMxLzyY95B997OsyOe7A4ly3Z4uVCG1EzbuoyI0xNCOSDJDQatDN54UZVVTJuCIAlctwBdh2qal4gXKIf6QU7N5nO/viMNgknsf6DTCr7DlvzvuM97dp/@3EPh5m3blwebhGScu6k9dBNnwc3dQTf/CLrJDXVTCRVEQt9tO/ni3eQCffEfeAf5gg3kInelv59N47/e/dyP3mb9K5@x8Pe/DWcuAU/sypHkO3eJ6d2vb8PO/1d2jXzcdpGHdlH849aJ@VsnxCmRH7N5Ip6K0@pjlDz2D7nBHk1NvvnHlau7xRltUzKZ5FoTC239Y7kmF80Hh2yJlciPW0Q/sYJ@Yln539ly@MVlnbMXICju/GXHH1Hq0OaIiYLmP2olvH/62ANL3MOr9e8m8i/TDS/bxyXtzhhlz8CQhn1OZHdyiTRxm/fv2cQycL7Tha/xJfIXK8z97S1i3XvYGCcXo4uxQ9rMeMyp5e/cKDgntn9ypScO/uNnBk6emymoNbwnUcDlaxML4oUelZS47mbrb2rZelCDgbGUDhELG/FFXhMprBs8XY/GBtx7kJxuowmUgTF2EcrJppFtsSgx0dFm9oT4M/D/f9lt5ZMg3@Dxj5us/gE3Wf3jrpF/3DXyj7tG7ts1ElvODV0n1zKsHIhmJlNuQPqnW0V2Dtmrz7ZO2elnu2zv5fb32FeHL9mrrReneA/o0ctnB/vbDL67L052mX97KX2@0B1ccs@g6Xf0tk7W@UI@X2KEeebWhRI70frsM7utXwPxbLha/2mPv2Qt3WvwWLvXujO2@XTQABezeGLXBNmK@FyTtDjhjusWUHIf5xHlWZ6YRzrN05UXCEJnozse/A3cfG6PZBBax0XTSv6mDYC3wRfQaHxKltZO49Q6CS2dLBMV538@ugZBKHx@wrZe7ODxxTv7p/uHL07Y3uExvB59hcfssJ19PDbm2UsMIsDnhzv7e/vbW@TBM5DPMrSt0Yb1@7KQRXCqlfZVd9i@yg5M1ArF28S1HrFIxLLlrgiXxYdWcHxPB0gK5935YadocALCXtk6/vQLlGr0tywaxZN7@e2nyAXkDoSVPG4agdTE1QA1giHRUlE5Q@qP2QoG1@gG1gS5M0wiT9I8saGz6DaaEXFCml/USgKbRA0JLQNuRCUPgq2zNyAgJ@LxzAahbEBqZD2QqaFhtStfMOpTcTAr6pExeUqrS0jxxNl9q83PBpceQPd8VTcl6zkcAA1CwoMDoA0GPTztSt9HIwkrC4ihh4o/eKxyjzf9wd4NSo24wVV4PENJiA6CCLUiNanGWo5mWLwdJ7Y1ce6guW3DoCguweMhOaYpTa60JA7kfzHHhrOyABkFLtiFni2VimDaDagBeHtP63ouS9STaA0GFUS3DL5S69LUQN0ju7CDG5aucRkBJVvBK7Dr4uamQOCk04WlCtMas8l8@PF2xMCvPzYexHw2kyKu26NC44IpjUu7D2bg2UwGvgsaQKSE@QUeKzTw@FWliMbuClJOuDZQJF729E0YHsi5M2zrExGErpN4Y7x7lxSVnAmihJb4UO78FXZvhv0BToTc4BlUdMwFKDG0UrKHs1G8DROTJQjmhvu4GMLBDL6uNyZSCysPMkWxEkckivL8glRbGm2GezBVoni@NthnXwP/zCia/nb5tjyaJmmhmuxrcy6e54yLGPBkJwePeekyXFg09ignKHlVI5GAd3zD3NzZ1/9Pe9fW3EZynZ@FXzEaaoUZARgQICmRBIeiLlyvUpKoUFS8VRQWi8uAHAnEIJiBBCwJV5x7KqlUOd6s440vlYvtVPKapOy4KnnI@@5/8C/wP9icS3dPz2AG5Hq3/BQ8kED36a9Pd58@ffp2etPdfXj/ZeVbH5ab1eoJq4V2jzcv@FAib7PQlBy6hzo7SacBZU8ToIVw0sHU8jwja0vs5RIMDJdTH4zvvVZDxfGy6mI4vk@XDqfAiwuXU1XovgmJ0CQ8tWLtVjaOZZZlStM0bAEQ605gFj3rypAyYSp9vYePdWArNKBGhqhH6HiNVlo@X6N5u8YNPdAsBWGncXMrfFs@sCAkij6W3h7VD6z7bmnXrkoq6kyqOi2possSuWaLUtFDJTReLcA9XA4H@vvqcJtLuePh4UuhPVyK9qV4q5TysXhY0rCuDvutJbA8uP1GsFD2cj4wD5KLaErSlXCWb6xImb8kxw8X2o76HsDg2DsKRjGolttkOEAPcRYvigNrlMDWYWKD6PnRw/3DQ8OkBza3IS3oPXz2sSfUIGJfl56O@B4yKTtHGU3yExtPMkQ8xZPMdllnzqy8HFUhbJCyqA@lLOIXwfv@VNyO4JGFTAi8eM0KUdZckrtzqYPCYwE8P8aTUEbcaFoBC5nFXOHBh53sk5KJ663MtnH42h8pY8abCmddtFQ9nulA0hDG4aB9gjvf2e33TbaPt2U@bGB5vz@hAuMh/C76yzeeQ8Yj3Cl2ki24pFlkk9KZFZLSFVl3dC0vaWF/dYFSD0zMhS2sqXVhHAvW2D6@Ic0cWtbEYQD3@Wcisnsm1juliqeQHb1B7XjQs5JDEBiZMA029nSpgOTNuRjCqDbUOOkqg1zvazeIm2PJZRPPGAnsRj7RO2DBb9xOq4d0VqBtl2ZV@Xqy4lEikZOs88zCyEhAvr2xsXYZdroUMnnlq2LzGJLWn9HZ6E1bgwxnIR0VAsl99LQs42MBWFJ1LswCe5bsMKmEYOpkjCmJstNgpPMHvPCz1MDMwYujMq4XpXO1jWmKt2x0HpF0dCJZKIPWhVVBudcs1P58eXaokC/N7/qXz487GxLhevj8C35w9jAYoarEt8Nb7BUVpuTbIZ6KizAFP7yuPP2yhz1C2gsjnr4eN/k373DjHWnOcS8KXuO5flekcsLRAJSSidtQzll7dH6BC1wXtGTKcXgnQKT1y8beKz6jssohvYAOEZBTA8EAcZkMAzX/pqXuF0LcNh4fLPArn0igbWC6qgKLN4sGzHu2cVWhLMNKHAb2iQqqcJB851qF3@JwvJfgjwYzFV7l8J73xkc32SJ0R6C8bY9U2K6gnEA94JkvFWEKYlqr9fuzFlW7ir7L0WDGqKB3BDMwtxwEKvQ6h@KZKhl0LNJO4qAmB8FMSgWtCCocmPxIl6XQ8163qJENHhYAsFg2hv6g6YjzU3ctMXe0xRWOiBsS0nvDXoEaBUUshpJDwh66lhUidLznNx06QCkUEM7J4obljrTnxwl0YggH/VqTv0ioOBkxgH8FE4JVXXgx5@O9VyjhYy/sTjxDvQGfkEpyDLKC70MZB@8ahwfP9pPQyHELbRRKJQ/soQgeC8aoOLLLlqHBg0l02uJA@TMd@9bjWAnBvxXRMBhrRPwzHSszIIgmdkvj/KJ3YRzD4D1SjWL17KZodFliVQanG0yG0fnF9IKadwqWngMicNeYO7hIcHehWkRPFBa2FAfai2ufeS20K1vSrUKcC4VQLlPhmyMQN65Tfd6eF@SrvlJ/QtNBzyQlrbQieolATRCgybM9xgWD0IPq6J4qkjHtZbv4ymeKMRyUHGchuGTcsW2R3JMqaTGzK2ZSystkK86EJUzhOCGEWHFuttELjAv/In4HXQ4qOPRvpmc7qrbRd7NoRm2IoW6XoFltatG8K6GVuVdIflvocKIF4/vghRhHdAhoPU2buyzjCTKS7wUypRwkGXegBTrqBQlC7iYLhJR@EbGVzWXc9TKSZHMc98dFdnJyieEykmTnEjOdbIq4r6daoxuAdcYPkuCXFkwEtfE1s@VAbBYyzuusRjqhEEWazrQ4T4v/2Rl5SDXNFCCPTfm11myK13X1ZEvpkzWicyAKr1UI6iByp4LDmh5eS4frQ5KxqyVPU2hMpYgBMzVSXd4W7EkkEfQWb2pxt6JLW/w5RltLDI2gcpoaKYlQDmklScq9JqYFUiQhKw5HFo2Ue2KStJRNqgk/0euoKV613qhIS9mkWv9YQK1koSZJS2nSBb1GijJZ98qgvWUtbzw7x47V4bSsvKnXnUQ80kinFdCHIugeuqElqHv@iR/dNWJDi745wA8K7fqm8Igtw2CCv3FHmT6UQJraOgsi2xgQtYVmS/kZGfNylG6@xYa5Mh4T9Pg6A41vOukxUejNYLAHJsGINDLEhEaOYtIU06uGU00jo0GXkQzTWDmHn3O0fo9Xznm649C@o1k27bnJbDUSWhTKJIPF/GhnR9aFEwUt38j8NATzhBGMjCSGEwct@SQwJpEKxSWO8iDo8mJnGbEacrJ2DOFN8ehmGgN3UxbLIhMCTPNyPnBDZRFjRC8BLyuUjiEnVYsYt66MISdsixiVq/NB86mssrxzZQyeCGZhVK@MgRK4WKfmyjkAzPmvmSVqifrAa1EitF3uJEVDYbYTvzrpssipqoH3BQkhQT9N/criQxjmuqwPtGnQleoDJx2L9WH53JN2YSgmzb3KC8w1TGkv9Bee3FIor8BqPa9h3AijHgwETn@g@ndG509N0VOLJAKQ1j1wEuN0T8cwRcLWdMTsQxoghAn8t1p4NKvVopWhZ4cH3zi896T19N4TnEStsI7C5Rs8LUPHdVaduglRvNrSojNFroFHLbAYBdLDWhzxJ2D2aRShl2Mx1cq5Rjc32YDCnFxaL3KG3lvjXYhyaGcwjYmUjlqbgeaxiAel1M3KG9OOKfURTJZKzNd2gROiYTkRnBCNFlzQJluc/uWQT6i8HL6MmLBjHPOdzLCp8/sSLy5pCQ2j8uZl9HveuINnSSrKaSm3Ih7Bx7kbOafCIxdiBT1G0Brwi2rVuC@d4or7a@1BF13eTvrk@PbMH7TPOr22MzodFfqhK9zTWMV@iE4uC3iY6tHR/uHz1jN8p2v/Ad2cwE@D4o4ePdk/eHGEMc8hak0E7x8eHhy26ID64YtnR@gxNBVk6oQCJSYTAQmipwfv3Xus0fBvUzDJF0JCmG/CP@HKp2z4o9aU/s7omkeZj0K06BEeuqaCSSmsbET@mRdM5ONt6H9CDvBlvHmCmzKQl3zVmBzSWLj8KeJiX6dzjYr4GE9GEZHSCXgrVRN2MgXTnIUnmIB8EYVgt9NpeodXlDEOL/IFIyuVFi/IYLKCuN/VD6l3YDd5Pht2LQknHHmWz70hUOJuU3ES9SubxbmNXiVHdGgonbhYhZGjSs5Ri9kpRQ2KU@kF7REjfdm1UZAX3oGKbpRQI8Q3UygB7yA2jFLJt88L@gNRIgq0Kr8fdW5od@iTNOL9mmtaG7FbUz7nC/mjgKhv4gaOkhH@@UzflCIBE/tTdJnjGG@eqzqj/7KwvMJsqdaxQn58Xt7rdvD0yANg@F5ksaMX8tkXy53Y7hIMtDAi3eLJOIAXe2OiwJQhy3gYNaCiovHM4BuEYaSqC0rexL9T4dq1iwdoLBA4W6c1TY5ld5R4SSiMmICmeeauuR27seFrCergMFPs6BS1LIoPdIp6FsUbnWIti@Kzj5nE71ulkmy8XaO@scGnmRPtmZH831XySkXS7sij0HFiwNOTy9GYQfYZQ1CXXLwOqo/ZAK5zdnspZ0noz/4DsHUskapCmTDjS9hegvz5H5rbvEJ3hVr6Oy6hpqDQOBFbXnyFGdcLHwgRlyyJu6RptJ8vQTNN2YrZab8fS8QHOULz2S8SNNli84lsd0PVn9zhuhanrcW3GtIA/7kI4H4ZgBanl/2LvI3yBV6Mrm8rFFmCGIBJ1nSSepokK8uLpVmu6ni1zCxrOsnqVbL87JciTzF@ZVD8SFGQrhWVmUn634mORkfzIVEWaciUeKfmWbzrm0t@kuRBT5ZF/ixGpyTN5Xx//u0033HKTPo/yhROSqDLl2z2zIr/p6tirOVifMgQlUpuvRWZolTKpfjsJzEfXL3pbrask3z@J5enXs1P/Qdx6niY35UDN1sNEiytAtXxoGQkJT1WaNx@UAEqJIMbbRhVfU7rcjgWiwtjyQLUVLS4cZaMrsvoWWb0mopOgc/ZwJJWEvrXI8Noh18YJNMo/k63fNngkpG7rm612Vwg3dplY11cMIe6UTaOuIqjGT27qQnHrcQkYxFaxNrC2JsXyApuZE5@wva4fTps4wOtYTB0xAsgflDdPwte@ThQjavo5sJ5FebNhr6KaU0ANI9zcfp6Dw9UAKvCqQif/eZ5OxK2u93J2WSAe2iumFehY6RqFV3G0URwODkLBSaOuPcn/gBK4KKlFpuIMM0bAZc0CoMpfaXsU1lnZbuYZbXK58YdckNHQcRbd@yPIsrMXZwLoMsnMlAhC39Ho5UmPF5QPycgdkXrivI89oeepdHjK65@WQsgvwgll1M1SDLSdaJhlPEEyNPJWQLhXLQ4nY1xOcYJ8caPtVquY815KDfG2MMXQtTtCD806sIHHbmWQRBxg2icRKmX122uJQJ6BuJ5lqRYL9dXMaMRRpGLIvIMrU6Wt/vktogutRIGoSlqagWwCGN4Ua@7q1A6iFB8ueavf/zxP5j2ebUqw@hNHX/YhjkDvUgSo@LPo@CZ/K3B4/xE3FVMYf9jjM3QPa/rn7XxhZpIgwbhykGGBkTkcxA0dFoVDEDfBCeW5gtGZoiCVa3ee/jQOHrv8OCbeBuKFxFIClLJUQi2DbPE1U4pE/HiYDCSCElYpHkiMkYiycQilSoVkqkSk3udvqWdwILa@s6fUW3RWn6AJ925X6YAMdpkpz64Tohna3VY1RBSgrEdvvOnjByM@PRsNnAwMoVgwteRB8IvlyKthXIxRXZ@v/rBX1J24kYJ2Hy4rnKmZ51n9FPssViQJZmt1Jq5pUpkQ5WQC3xpFX33pwQW8iPdUhEWrulaUYFkF/tHf2sQBm4@QOtpKY0ETulSoE8YSO0eUM3l4lUuxfse4/V82gXQgTqzZBGfwDjpjPHSkKUFVy@pvl/9QHAM9H6EeyZL8riVYLeQ2Rj/prcspRXNkde@Gn5uC/9QBxXXXPMQeaDKxPn4l3E31YvJrpNZvq9pvTPFWmaBP/6vLOmjM@bQe9ADOMPqTZXZV3J4/uu/UfjTwrXpJQLz6x9/@pO4jNPckk1zy/Np3Jumi6WY5vF@LaWS3schwyxNc5viF8lsEj136mo/8wB@nlfv02RlT/O6PIi@6vTTS7p9HsgnEkR1@OmlXT4P63sSK7Ozp4uV092nud1coud09BT@rRw2oTP@q94Zp8taPrfP54vF3xM4Gnx4eXShWapVYeGskmm7Y9ToP3rmxf@7aW507YdLbbHh4oJFBXA4a0rIHlJNd/Sef55@U37Odk0cWhPOFmSJtFxqIheYmrQHYUZWrvu15VXHqoPpXkYuu79ZJoV5tTr0@NL9ZNTDWQft353RzGNM23/4eEC2Zvw2tSVY2zBd4ds25J7gmFhu0g5OuCA@CEc@h@RUAz1A92C6Qf93VHErNQ6h@ca1NMogYJPoGi2n41QodyIiZhKlWjNzUsHz1MyO8DOlgXh21eHZFVaWKCP5kY1jLlXe3/2J0kiqloIkegqydDnmP4tmoCNGtFdOHjuETZcP7SZ@qYlUMlQOAblD97/o2iKVXb4tqZHlIX//z9VA54V4lrUH5cErr@TxHx/HxIrJHQE1/clfCcCyb8UqIzfnv5ANH7KGysscR7Ir5JOTzU//2ETRzq4kjm5cPskSiLlzLOPRU@PF8/1D4@DF0bMXR7ggoztGVHPw/IkeT7tZL9MENrlIsDCXbcA0v87TWS2Oxcsv@6W6TcX/q0@x@Axbcs1VU6umpel@mEhXk@mW1BE1xZVrSNTPQnpetADuOG9RWtfdFDUEE@hHwwj7a@jBF0HGCxPs8FmMbSz@fGVan3WLjBnnCk3/dRZLW4zJX0zAoQ4bwK0Z2H7u6v9Lxm9HMmjJaoa7d27Wbh7jQymky08i/W1LUGJls1H44osVYzSLToNhvbBiqPVXg9Zf0WcQr3K@CnkNNxz6o5EX0VMExok3xAVofJzND9CqQAcd6Psevr/26A7wtgQ3eLm09SpsIVBLADmjmWHe2DMLBf9sFIwj46OB35Hf8R3R2@vyVzgL0dVD6HlZj1EfjWePooMh2g5V9GoYBfxdf5ca3S2FUOVA4QfOeDKskksIb9jDpWs6Kth@DaydQnZQtF4LyFpYLMvG3ePQQxdS5stpv2/SBWtv0HvuYeWihWcob@eP8DKfCcyfmnjCbMV4GkTeNl@JlveMlScNqnHPKIoFs8qA31ykVf2i9hoHnkrD96Zo98TEg0tiTZ3c85gOLRJDKtOmJXYLz2n1gyCK6eVxC5GAN28SKbCM@JAOCy/6/Y1LhM94eXj6UzBRMgwRQHzEP0WmcQBlRNyAxim3x9hx1L0aMAJnYv2/to0uuNCeBXN9W54/9vEsc21zG/1nU0mwQrGZxPJtbRNjJvzgOr4Kw/fH9XKUXMEJEHKD0GNF0A/wheqg84oOeqBBDTNslD9HxqEJ0UG3JQPyw442pnpa/G3HZ3ftPT8kAkxZPfnIH4kqKidEtTM5CR3uC@T93A/DibdxZ3OdGKK3ByRpL@gmSOtVQEb3b1Vi7jQ6G6hSbEWn4k1t8tFyJh/dJk9Z0ClJztAXQhvP5YEA3rZJdKAqEyWFWrC2yhz2cP/dx/eO9h@WjUptA8n5EomitbTK5egSxdMhSyFGmIS7r9O5vc5CboXl4l61aAvW9/RqL@kMSwAwt8aoa0dW0aVkwnpmYFBrPdRVZfUmknp/Bc9TYXdDViZj9CxsysqVPX9lxUSRxrxWUAQTdh2ksQvq6gn8AsWzQJSrK6AGhHZr4ZQH3f2T5Jo71ysV1ae26VsFFGulsst3wcwHMFa@NoqHk2FC2xap77SNIig59GjDqu16kfSCYzaMU7f4TlhsdGE8VwbCG2tin8tneIZ95MLiijsK7s9k@1kTubMEFWIf15q2LQKK//s/Rbsxj4/uDazIPsch7iNXum1zWKnvs5crq8gzNkj2kRPBRPMBKdfIjRoqQSfozRx6Nqz34BQmFtZHeh4jyz6nE0hd112zzyHL8QjPio5AGXpHgGg3MKyfCIMfUMdgY1Rfvhyi67pbuE/3/pPH70GTH6IPiDA6/qB560a1XCzCbIJ2CV30xm08PHjyDEf7se3QqP8uDNeiXsZtlYmDi@94u4e4L5tYtCr2QtCcJ14kSh/enx21T56COWYV21AFSSOrre/M4VO0eN5OryPXTDYu2EgnLlGdjr1@gzed56H7xjqxGxH8O9Wz2IAs3Hqd0CNI5OIlv1St@0MYrd87evLYLe60DUR1M3pFsdRRwgGCQgJjYRDNwxOig0/eoVRFfLeCBAY@paK5myzLTrW9W2zM57n8PA7aPfbKUYwFuGdNykLixu5ikzbGsRTMRp6LATy0fWP/yCxD2vHEszGQ3iGYkdJih4GuzIPFDTUFDYGz50jjuus3b1IYJpmErltfXbVxC2cOaHRPE2C5Y40b83Hb7VmqItsj36HprTflvMg4qTv1ansYvvXGYbV2u766ceduMMa5fc8LuzdDUCFuG59986PZTbxsR1u@J8Ggf7PvD3BR6fr6rc0D//7vvr/1/PZDq9v5nZpZNl@F9A7veKQzMG6/FTv0oGPHXZYuYmIImN12ddR@HVTXe6vdzdXN2p2ed2fD21xd2@xueGtbna2trW5/fbPT27rTvrPR7VTRtSMlcc5og99k8cds@1fLNs8w26yvbvX7tdrtO72Nrf5WfXVtbb2zudFbXV/vb9baa2u3e/XNzlZnudUW81MABSv1Lo4daQ38Tr5xV1jQ7SK1/X8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#  ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>  ;
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}  --[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
OOO    program-id.h.procedure
231    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
uuu # >>IF 2>2
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
  
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/=>+&&1=1~-<>8;t$f U=B~+Num4839195>E ngt;reaeidgenulohar Cr#ataPr$s 61 47consPLle._=>al{} 3>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0  )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77 );}__attribute__((weak))int main  (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write( 186 ). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))   -(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint ("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

shortC code ends up in the same place as C99/C11. It is separated from them with `1&*z(N)` (`1&` is in front for Prelude).
Capital letters are replaced with various stuff in shortC.
`N` → `stdin`, so `*z(N) == 's' == 115` in shortC, `*z(N) == 'N' == 78` in C.

shortC requires a space after `0'0 0'0` for some reason.

There were two obstacles to add shortC: `W` and `\` outside of string/char literals.

Grass `W`s were moved out of C/C++ code, it is possible now because of spare `w`s added in [answer 224](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170087).
Note: on line 183 two consecutive spaces between backticks break Pip, hence the placement of `186`.

Naked `\` was previously used to separate TCC (`z(\,_)`), now TCC is separated with `"\??-"[1]` (`\` is for Pyth). When GCC is launched with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` it processes trigraphs, TCC does not process trigraphs.

shortC/TCC/C99/C11 code: `1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""`.

Comment: Still going strong after more than 2 years and almost 250 languages I see. o.Ô Keep up the great work!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It's still a bit more than a month until it's two years. ``</quibble>``

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah, I thought I stated **_almost_** 2 years and **_almost_** 250 languages.. :S Ah well. Btw, does it user older compilers on TIO or the latest? If I paste the code in [05AB1E (legacy)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/Q8EAA) for example, one of the few languages I'm quite familiar with, it outputs 0 instead of 26. This is because the stack only contains an empty string when it tries to for-each over it with `v` (on the first line), so it doesn't reach the `ef26q` part of the code, where `ef` are no-ops, and `q` is exit the 05AB1E program, after which the `26` is output implicitly.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It stopped working after one of 05AB1E updates and I was unable to fix it. Polyglot is supposed to be tested with [this version](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122) of 05AB1E.

Answer (score 7):

## 237. [Perl 6 (Niecza)](https://github.com/sorear/niecza), 11012 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rbyNZdiD4WZz9B/vlilQln0EySFGiSJFKpR6Vqlam1JKysqolFTNIBslIBSOYEUGJTKUK7Z5Fr3tsLDw9vUbb3nG1PetZ784AYyx2AQ/GxgD214ExvyH9aWEs3P/Ae86590YEX0pldbe9u2hKZNzHuee@zj33nHMf0dTc3j/8Qww/7Ng2x13T9pinux5rO8a17mTZkzF7rBluqVCMRBBq2@kO@7rluZVIjKmMWfoNO7BaRhvCmGdf6ZbxVncgrsDYwLG7jtZnXk/zwGNAKrarm@/67zzWsvt9zWq7AFlk7FiDyM6wdcW0pus5WsszbAuiVhl7YZlav9nWGEDozsDRPUJfYmxT7w@8cR08a4w9sx1XxxxbuuvaCLEehigDhOYY9uH280@nMG0w9qkGhRmY@mgqezXPXhq6055Koars87P9/enQAvuOYltsH6sxFVVkLxxXM7Vp/Ktse@jZB950eIltd3VLY4XsRrYwHbnGnjjaTJJ15uhau2OYetawWkxhPd0c6A7DENaxHeglTzfL@XK@sR2kzLYwbTmInEJbkx@mOV0XIu1rHZw69N/A0Nus49h9plnuDeSkbuQDeES7wcxi0Ztqi0I@1C0FNewphD3FsGeVqYeNaRIolDB0@@hgOnyNFQ6nw9ahxK2rzmzfFMrsxB6Mp0M32DPjcB7hFfNsr2@/NnbsNtR5Ki5cnWJhcgC0oH9gaLHXLhSlrTPXMgYD3eOR0Nu6Q9HQ8Mw0rKsIH2/Hjt0etgyrC3A6ZDcYetSlbqQFyepsIEZtFh0sRkTAwaAIp3ZfDxfRheEKneYO9JbRMVqcNvSRp1sudLebZQY0z41hmqytm5AgwN7KMNdmQzcU1DS1XraVjSBtYS6sf2Uyg7UGA8ajoBpQpP18menYYOwtxJs9l40GfeYafYj2Wnano@vsrT7oQfJI244w@LQGU9XyfSs6wFg6VG3n@EtoNA/b0upAudqsGYKDQlCBqbqaZUPbOczS@nwktKC7seqAxk/Rse0shrdt3bXiHruxnSvW1Fsa1hkzc/VuRxuakKPRwb6AMWC4rG/DE3rQYlAsSIzUTrgxs8jcimA2sm/1ATAl7FsbaQU6WnbxjaMBcTiu6ETP6ANpGF7cZbrmGsigIYmrW20ii4HPum2obbjH2bUBTAeaYugQbld3aNgTXoa1AJSaT6iJG8fwgBywFtvsWNccduboepITqe62tAGSaDhLyMzGHDysSJaocnMzvne0Hwfq5Cmy2gCo0SmeffeziMayNbbSqMK3Fo1WI3vPd9ntygW6@RQBFDxwElqS1b5mbu7iQofvSG3mus5dBLBGoFVMlrMHXk5TBlBAxYMC5jR0oku5LmQHZihjtjnVB6Exw6Ha0BvAANnnGapZa@g4OJkFjapdQaVN2@pCe0JlnaHFu3wtD10A9Nd2M0y/1pEGeB/ZN9TCZz2gEPgH0BBX5fMrNSjMsDAORYvKfF3bHBIcpHQ9HIzQKpAUMR502OesoxkmJoF4RMVL7eguECemGVpt7Pm@YentLJPFIJbjwEC8huw0QEoBMBr6IcZChQJg6AibqopR73/nD9rdLuDZbrVspy3I9XMg9hZJAhoVFuZyhgRrW5pJxQK4DObOk0MG15pptInFadZYZEGFoFxv7KHZZjRQbwwYcj0NJhoduEPL0zmR20MPyphhfe2Ks0ODUy5UvK81oWMpA8qbqq2wxzvQSy0Y5kQzSn/odcpMGeyxuJv7KrFVSWwtX@hQuGQ2mVrJ5bpVILhsioLAF7@Pcj7fnpgmXU9zbaMdGYy9nm0VmNJi0VbNHuhWIj6BI56JO814MotsOpGsGrVWtmNY7UR8E2ixDhnHk9VWrXVuVC6rU8nDWQKaG0SDw1VPtJJRZDU0KK5zfZClssDJPleEKxRnuw1scozOhoKxYabDrnlAjCQ1pEsbCQT4UNY1dX2QyGfVJLIJhJtbb4yYV9MpHKLCFeMyHY/F0@GqEwao6URFcbCeGTayLXPQw/kcGsVyB8BzHaTdlgbU4@KM5oEEm2FNomuaBoGzEE@80ePAtZvASCUd0ZDkQw7TK8goBYZgCE2OZL0dGsjABGAse@4MNzZtlIyoTDjzAOuwMFOtC10DiXlFtnlFeE4UMlmlKwsYCmJr6qysNA0YBDjcgKcLmg/VDcCLBQ4D2PggCfGevjbGWY3LBcGAwTlNY31gD86YtXTkOcB8dD6hYCZDGn8uiPnM7rC8UiiVJsfYzBDznNy28j1g0m9z944krHx4MCGjYR3QKkzN6g61LvAL24IkWqulDzzBqKAmrgesaHq@oUBFTJ5ZtxdZeTydN00iUjYK8kAmz3tPTIUachehpSggkKHYy1Uf1jYcYEswk0/lDgDXU5lHXyHIRAFeRRcUQUoAQGT6SG8NPeBqQMA3PaPVA5rF0lmcL/JJaDp7CArnDpxd6fhZY2HU@qNCJJvzg7AYC1Eo2KOzeGByRVT1iQDq/HDA/Zg1tz8Hse0XESaCUGg2p2WB9j6As29b9hyk0JA@WgSZjOH9AJLYKUrEMHFJsYsGqy8m@10EfQZcA0Y@0F/P8wZuBeYJw@sNm1mglNyZMz7wjiwklpznjA3P5u6maTeBLbswPnMyh1xr2DRGUxWiML8PX7uRaxDAOi6rwcz9ZghUl4h3XGCYFL6DwKGoKDFuQsF/owBIQFloqETHJVa8D0zldGy1EtEJooxmWBTHbjQJDkzoN81nKLxNFvM1BE2XEsHChcnmECrnOi1yKCGZFNEjOBUrsjRRtQeWMbIUjcJPRzNdHZ7W0DTRO7Q4l0twWSHJbiNLS8DaEpSd0R@YRsvwGjyWPXokZAq2DPotik0dlJmSkGZJGBKywFAARkw/HDrr2ack7CaSUJGlu4mMdcexHZ6v13PsG0YBCBYJN@qO3Ufuzl6SwIUSNKj0hoXqqZhLaSrV5ooQ/pxK8nI8nn1tG1biNr68vByvxOswYy4vb4FrE11b6EqDa4tcCrkQLosuSpEhF8aeUwoMu4zfnUvMo@QlDocRzvZvjUFCO69UipcZ7VwVzwI@k9DOMGMAtIIPwBNP1mroTCaj9RuoaLbZmaz9Ds56py3HGIhG@Ey71rhftEKRmgE6znZQMaii8HJ/m/RrDkgXoAy0egknfnGev7i8uL1opy/u4hlMnaxqtSZUCvJL9LNdxx6CGJI8X60o6mUyeV4E4aNZi@fjqUSirIAaB5pI8pNyMq3x1k7EdZgNExcXcWhU0T7nrZ5D@EaZQjLpNxWUAwUekLUT8extGfJvJi@T6TikTcYzoLrV4nFomRY2gkuVxrE00UBHJ9/hDbOTTkdoeINWit@Z6RTCUOmdTH48fPsWeRfH0fQpzBxqXMobCIDcgSVhsxg5pbTKqGaHIR@dyONTu8O1oh382Tvcj@gj6q1Pj/b3TmqUTU9zr0CmULoImwNZGVrFaWeBG5jDth6ZBwNsA1ytoCRoOMDMu60WU2xGYEqLFyI0XbTYAmzAa0jwtJli9ier4PagvDsTdSAkFE4p75NfWrJIHHxumfws94Fj75xOGqf6VyBPsJZrovCtOLwC4M2leGCbHr6OUWEHpKNZIGACbYF82fZtAZZtKcgLpTpnhzPiBhGAoDCUtlCSMCZgEHHHGIFKHEN7ihD9UWJF6X/HtkA51bMviRtGGTByNFXp2bny/zEXpLItNxidIOmDc2BqLeD3k@guouwCEAIHyuXmxySrM4inlQPS4z9URxClWpqF7dc2SE8dGm4Pmxd0CZwFnA60KiqpaNyhVjtgLZByu9DS@sjwuNYKI/wUkzzV3EQS9aRtrmcglaGMjIWSZjsSYO0WaPg6yMoYy80lbM@6NhzbwkbO7gFqYEVV7IMp5POaF8hoe/ugsLu4fechhxabCVZDbRvGOt24LRdGl2WbdtdmKQBA0sxmOWEfWGjeBC3H0wYwooy31EDbXdsaT9Ggrvv24rWir29qCJkj@OxrmAXY/EoHAAvqfHrwvT0QQ9RSPg/ll748ffxKhrBM1xEDWywAEIseJtIN9uT39EFvPGH2RfrgdhOPjIc0MLklSwMREkolRvhbShoe5DwExrmMakvXvLrvkU6AxruwXj1R@wlphQ8bqGFsKhhDZVNMIJ3p8KB/kXFd5Cb4lm8qUDp929Nyn2eBReNPBCVkxWBRNxdfjucUBX@jFMUKdZZr69c55FIB5tGe3pqLe6TrrRzG4uTGpGNu88jIBU1zAR@LfqCa/CnbwE85Xf9uOo2MnUrn580LDZP8WW@oR/RWz2bRC1AxwjWLwgTRA11ZgZYHARD1Ej@ZWACLePYQ1Lq2bhp9wzsgg71poe6SJeadRa4lYnGpIUBwbOggkHODQzDJoFE9mKOsLoc/AU5OWEHFz/ImdfR2LhVge2bbDuiVLlPJplDwm74vInK2O2hnvREg4Kn2aH535Tz//Gh3r3G8ffa0lhu6Ts40msAj2nqjD8qsCcNhwQfLhhbCPaAdw7L7BtRIonx7ZZ7YtseFB1w1eNgnhgkljsPdxuHBk5Ptky9F4WhGN/pDU8MyVlamAHwcpwRzL5qW3bRBtrCGCzGBcHH05OhQYvnsxeHBdmN37/joLITm9dA0NHWUG1x1F1XoMwRhajbPm/7IbE8u55CaOmFFEMwGda4qA92UKQr8KhjGM0WtLIsRKCLj9KgoaAXW0M7tsIKa39hoN7VyWV9rt1ZX1ztap91eLajlUqdcKpTy8LO@tqGzdwSuKPqILDfg4lYRNCBhHlB4eqjZVSnhgCraAollPLdcfuw9hWuVSvr66oa20drY2NAK6@2iViiv6/raemc1n9fX1HynWVbLxXsLFyoGilaBr08WIBh1aCygSGB@CXhMDAdeeJD1bli7UCistUqdjWKhXcqvtpsb@VK53VTXteaGnu@sFtWC2m4V1IpMixZV4BI96DCUKi0QTWWUokJkMiIn03AX0wqrXHUXDGeliCxmIFfNUXEQEasYMRRr5miaFeFrGN7HRfJAYiWvHygAywSIa@VZpykDNzDQXyWfWD8Glij45Lz4xYkE5ls1f4fIb3CdPVSPW1Wl8Guv05kILlDwlYJTlhkEFymYr7JPrm@Lys5EzQX28a0SPr46PxffTNRcYB9fiePDVf356KZi5oH6yNYIGe4CmItrKmIOoI9pnTCFdw4EcWWKW7RtQOQ1N3phIh/3BuHG7QEBKtosIIIkYIH3g2o2tEa/bwTAMiQUBWoWTHzqWpC45Ce2p5LaRhDsg/NmLZgNUC@GoXEiQ8JRfiLegnJzQZgmC7wBHXswDg2l2wKve98QYzRE3EU@Fmi5HJUMZyKSUz7fRtB4zVdyGmIXAY50zjzOQEo9tEG3ODRwTaMzwU0ivnXiIhKVJpZJI1sQUwiWkJhyPX/tKxpGxBmlYV3ZZFTwXY18Vi0hFh9F/8qcTdkBNYx@JkBnCjUbw@f2frNDP3MAUCCZtlpSBJmEhVgEYoiWO6EHGofnlWDSzD2RfVPvDEFDzDUNC90fAFM2ygTZaTaNRaDQErgrQz7ngFXYyRC09EJ2NatKkwAuK8F8xm3UZwdHBNjUSMGdXBthE43vDR0PUonnf/l@Gzphtot62pj0ZN/RsPQboo/Owh4TSdFDP/N7N5CIqGHI9SGULQ2XozXTd8xHTb2vKD3N6aM6KrobCBR/gBLuoTVecm6nks/5mVQYNfLkGgyzjD5rzYEm2KnlIp4ZGSBMW2tTM3AzgaFTIgc7m3eDPuIKc0gYBBazKKM5qzos2Ebh9YbekP/izokPdaMxwO99Q1RA5ktaU9VBfdCahn5Ppzva1bBtKyAFU5WxYGtzYIPakyFT6ZjaFXc20Dm/@ryCjtHtgqwlnovAbnqg95HCnruhx4fowrWG7kBpQmd5MHDIR0Ohf08Ojsl/F4EYYiul71jcaoZJPw/odJ@4iFxA3KWGxr1eSqjRjKlmNrXmGM0YvY@nMsyQhELgObVWOp0v4jTqr4uHt2ktTo9zL6Xf2Jifmu8y400yT/XM8d1lCjeuU53FfrMPdCxMXEZfM5VCO@RcyNGlWT1wzQElm5bSMjUXSMsT3aFfQ/fRz33kjjNTC1RSJ3DdQ@xBceT2iEUr7YJtiVHdsk3DxaFtLuKg04uTQZ64z49@QuZ6Y17DtknOdHuK75rPF@yWh8vcCwjtAVyOrzDjGn6IcrL2okZr2Tf4XSha9Oxrnf/On@jezi3VAziWYhJJGK25M0q79SFKxa1S9DO/Ha/mlstrmXPDJ8eANP@EldcH0rVrmLbLTun3vmYBWdp1@e98ig63oKFZCq2Vhd3zk4lCDVhWWKAX9Ktmdm1zrdzNafCzsPOHTgfnBPF8KPfzuZeqfph7SfnItlTxXMj2r3LO1Yf6jpZtHNzQEHLeMwPPY2FiwXZxBUGTwF1K8yu3ny9TymyO2xgWdYDT6t1oY/n8FjPLotaVM8tgTPI2iH@YYKMMDs/hMvi3yW31/tzaD2NPM2jXP1SJUOdemTpMZPQ706WskFc/MoWazz@cWXXMoT7U5/Kqo@ZrHffW36OFPLxQeVGNFWEJRmsZ2oF9qLdCf3xQqXEOR9@9DEYzDRjkH5R05vK7AcjoA1S5j8FxjI7ZhF1rOJjo3Aktzjq5v@V6Azmy7fZEITHmYzlS@cPy1IQg7@r0vVe54sogrvvVivl8Xsg3Idv@hOc@pavop31t8N@JjCkkyHnCVDIHZ2BWhq42rlwFDbwP40aFRRYAAt7YyFmGpXtj/F3UBfO4a9O2zY/pMmCybQPlNZBCcRHsQ103IwuJnXEssHW4aClpdhZZOfgEJLRRaD1UtO/r/bAZ@kHdquDyPYzK7pT3frtPyKj9oVxgWidjEt9GYi4WNIUFRc2Ws@v3jkAuvtpN3dT4Y7S2eh@@jWzxXny@iCLkYlrnw7VBvhoYrC7HpvjUYAyNZbRBqenpfZ2892gDWvv10JWPhUAjG79zorO09roo3cAAxmDh78TKY0h08mwL1DBPc7o66jEm7hAQoYuYsVx5mNu4B32tq/Pzdfdxy8C0gduoufYXOOcbOSp8B14LkvFtMPeTAgymK33syudchM/GLejPYf/Dprmpcd@iTVsfGujZ3NwFlw/IhlbP7lk9vcd3Rfm@RcMDKNLjJyPvqwSUX@y4YsSjwru2wq1r2qb5kNZFHsk5pm135pZrDw@ttSHpR@Eda02IEI8Pmv1gfqdGool@0djp6UOYplzbswe6Qr5FoCYaiPjvIk4qF8G@reXpXqsAtIh8flv8H9RHu5rtDQb0aAzMoUs/lFShs4bzunKfsnkIVRge34bFaVfv2s1Wz/hQkZq65lnGVU5agbj3Xm12EGoFgym7GJw1DWg8Z5xFaqiF40/xcbCoS0PLPHNrvzN0nDHW3bNt5pr2TcAVJneQ@MZavsaAjkV5ijXTOdEkA@DeQrmH7p6FDrHEupCkSNRGsVrR8yCmqAvtRhMbXAXrorW@BVLQVL2pMKH1tY8xeIoNH2T6M0J2WQifoJSJZfi5U5PVG3bdWcbGzfFtEKjwZ24Pb3fxDPFUB/POhPlGs8Rj7vTrrzzet2BSunfFJJsT652KPlxo/zKNgct/mdIpzMUyu34@CzWer/@KrmjrHb6oga4PiXB928GTUiArKC1Hd1toE0c2ywUjzlIsuwvsVjFZACxh51Zhdsl@fk@HpzLli@d6V8N9pIcGbik15xABYJ5evX8I4u8ONdf47tD29Lk4p1fxH4LymdY1Wk8nekEilK0rNh3yxwS1Y9BsR9z0DJcOrEjH/BHCyYxW5OdoYVNmd//k9/3mkZAAJPa3M@WAyX3wvgMN/xivzc1rUrwUi/ELmZrhkUlVPOfWc/6Oh/tsCzfD/mDoisf83GnzUdi23L@icPfGAI6nvAEGy3qa6c23P4dMqiA4iZkucC4Sp79nmHaXfa@cZyBnwcyL0vUCwnoC8@6x5sEIsOYQK@X/wFVOtFgoDq/cGyAEvcgUwzK8@60znqeBwiOfWCEuU@Hxytwh/mYffywG5Wx@qxzeK4rAlD1umXja/2PFes5qB@PcKZ3GR6d/IUCY2EU2@o5AKCcPS78JK1/3rthUcMa0raGn4PGF@2aPtXtnjwoblddC5MES39179iIpqaTba/F9vR8SKHXQ6oauOQ5cC3cNzCE@wwLJazH/nU0h1YNdne5sOKGdqA9Itz3AI2LE7nfteWrM8Rhmn4/ShWACGfZ39RYuIz6oDM/tZyClwZQ2AIbbP9FxD8AUj1mcGJMe2i3NhDZrPyi7U0I/Z74ItGhtoDeh783ANV8MW4R8V/O0BaITWQVJ1fNdH6Qlw2zqzmu0@YXdizTY2UI91UekcywmKD5SFa/V4rI22uEmxlFIDa@w04HNj47fQxM@G4LJg34evpCexS3bE5PhXD1stp5H13wnid7m5xUXVdTRm7bJf3GmWcAsLIPvG9AcQ3dzh4Y1HFEYU0Cam6/b8N3L@ew6WjTcHgzBGwNUaX9TM@5D4zuk3UBdEDt7rGvNpdX8@YrMxAbqh28Y6mlOy8ZlMeH4yEWx0Em4D3B5f4c433XQBAIaAbvTWkN5ncIHimr2m336WayQTPb2id7E04ZNOjrraaN5IuXkqTkROHVuTTI6HP5rLHEMak/yw1PdtM422erGgH6I5d/MJRWZ3XNDb73V7s1QnGygS1j84/puRpy5gTDDEed63ay8UShG55Oo3eVOeRbDKwWGqB96tpNlBJdIaOl0MhnhiXBlvmsBmISiK1HwugR@24rLYAb2CNbosPNztnI7quQr6h2rsWglyi4vOVb80OH9vdGA7jM54cnPV7TL2kpcUeIr8QurwvJxH1w3QfqcC65NwHYMevDyBk3A7zqy6aIiv8ZVfh0E9DdetdLTrLapsxcWLZ@AuODwSw34jRlnuA3wr/@0LW6goZuW@gZogNAgeIOU3dd79s0Wz1fkDpOnhjfYIA5QFkx@n4Kys81AivVaPX7xjH3DXuyflcV1FuK6KvAcczXfLwXvXFxZwKN5Hu88Xhr/mJXI2E8lKwWi0bBvAbdpez03y04NOnU3dIJ99OIOM8tz0HTYzrAD1tZxxxUdpiRruWnbV3TAAkvy13/KL/GgI5XiqJvMni7vCeWIJydVujmj1bKHUGqJ5K3u2AIkgY0MqsMQ16bo7igKT@JBQ7pdBChSkXdrUDb8go2d7VOm7LE43kqFZ@GrRiexsn3y6efn@cva16yf0//L93PJW9Fw0U@UjTU3mmESpHqHhBWOLkF0EBtn0ZVRlGfonzc1hMBzw/sDb9TiRIZHTiWN2fZAjBq6H4muA/KpURyzT6Cb@llestGnq5WIYPUbumSDDjZZKO7Q1V4uDDDwJgk1H3W1lcSQL5copx4rQYZ4UYkGLn4ZE53AxAsjMMnKiL1jPSQymDTVUh58vCFNvKOkX3si9@MWw/ukc7t6c0h7Ba8L2UKpRtVZadQ26@SC@djGu4LOv7oYFfLKxWh97zLnyka9uBh9ki98Aa1uO5DqUQ5H3t7z3duVbD3/7p2rjVk0ehev8n3dwCZWbo8PjvdOz7bPXpxCL9xJ9rPPT75IXoNURIfZerZJtzBBu@Bc/BH8x/fhnQgJtqKxTbzjMJmMhI8dEaho66gSXeHOEGuaSP2B5PPSu3oofhZA8LSOwSRFHcA0gH0IxIathpUfDvAuKSbSivtwiMoM5PE4gPyGwd3zc3gpNVWU1aCxFGisBzYVW1zZLR72kBb7IJb7m21rLgi2mJ/fuR/Pqzi3Ce5@KfUewET5i9ebY7m/3gRzT70B1A@Vafa3Dw5fnOxNJgMaoydx3dpGSZy348wZRxrfZCEvAKJj7iIhLjXVoixKCbhXTGb8GkLdu9GhWoI5tvo8MVEolT8aCQgTWqaGt4BeVnlbJBJUApRBqlitqeOAHWMUKqKco0PobnkVfSawH/VRy4JnowJzjK5zzOJHVgOxiuaSQ@@YmLjg13E3LP5k5IjDquEcPXT5mFswVfmzjsvgPzQrSVfhko2YmM7US6awAnxN3epChSVsssrnKLbCGyK6wsse9cuLN/FBmdqvNTIE01ZucYwOZmlTG@C1XwL6ue3pFfZmaNNRfclMfPmCLoHU@K2Z1LX8Oki6AgBkbJBO5bxF@A72T2sonXHRjPh7mOaGFk5UAMTvsBSHaT0Hbxjlpxz5ZXK8yW1xb5mcKkl1csU9Rb6U4LJrwzVA6KdO6KCMYwKnxNqIiuMdsHRJA9s2XZBJ2jB9g4Ti4VQLwkmWzhfxQ0aKxaIxoMmsLzJmWDSCsG5t9h4rmEpvQK1pveKJVwiOMLshnPHNZUWBluuCrifOKlXwClTSGCrMc4a4fagen0kii1Ahl9Lz@mYIcM6Nfhd67v3v/AG/xe/CA/ePhHuUfwK@3xK@Drh/W8aoKvj@pe8rgO/H3PdVDrts9uoykb0wSCw8jAV0@Tg6UyfkCfLaV6qL39vY058fHDO3hReKYl/2QYULugk5DNIcqN1Af30gimvqYwTnOQRdGOBJnH8OJAJ0BfSB4g1KNJSf7lwm8AKrSi6HBUdTcZa2cOkjvsRK91m9GeI9jiCE5dZKa6tqDgqpXEuEdMVGF0@UcITJZAV4YuTaGNRegbq7ubnJom5LM/XaWpXTRm5F@6oYfeUXdAVgI1xROGeQBpIEKSCuLpIlVrS0msSkOJHF1TjytLbNSQ2kwQQ5ACSJwZY8lA/ipi2aCujY0kceSUxjqQABw7bs0AWuEpECiDhuvG1wejgGp0TQehEaoNlwN0RfItgpglWi84j1/Ct24V1Yl@LWSQaE97M5pGuB@1/MuYqSUxZeOjJ7B2Ji@gZDrA17fGrZaATah9KyRCFXKObUtWSIQqMCFZQXh/o7QAmDG5hFSzde2wN3e2fv4LOj49OZu3AIMj4NFmfx@mb6Qslmzi99R9wv92SjPtnPnT57si@bMlyqwAyDEMEWuulizsttuqQLcn/JD@TM5k0RMxmp@Ycipr0pyj5tPZ3FHsTmQoA7/DzATK6J5O3d@eVm/cKKzWT/bt79prFsCokLXBcu3W4any4mFtG/uv0Mr253s/K0qYpHTfEMkmdfBQdhRUAogoNLLMABItmchJpDsbIAR9w@E9w@UeB3x7vE@rgNh26d9EsUgjyTt8zj0AouSxO3hPU0t2cazQjM3W28OY/f8SEvsfBvB8m6A9PwEskIWT9qKAEBE0uIu@ZHlVGW1pYSdMcp4cqw@y4ek/iSERgEgC9@PHR77NgesMD0tKtL1wkIImx3yBcbdPbZsA9wHXqc6MhidRBNFEgMDRX3i8oVahhZ4t6xURrvdoP8zvH2MVHxbL9dSoyS2Z4@ahtdYOCJZAZG@icqSFT@6V@sNN1FZsWBx/EW/hTPYYSb9KOunxsFyLVzLWtYbX2UwPtUKpcgmmJ4/ObldTwZnaEBugNvR96aNXUZnhyImidGRHCR3NRg29jwB9nkbYUbG3gnDR5khm6BHE895xCcMD8lOn1twBJDuqXRZVlG3sRFwsq4npNkSp1f9GCxdJoUanhQBAjMCNohFxEOS@ClxolcDXoHQ12rjY@3xoCdq9nsJbgpkyRbQWPaDkzlaIZKRkBBgiQVQlvDvmUVLBGn3iynPEiD8RG6NorhVYVzoulyQVyPg3EKbUG1ZvVHoet2ghHIW3VjoyJ6Y5LVbDAgi1kun80B2jksRAqo0L7iXCq0Gl6@jbe0O3rbALbw@Du6ZenQQEAzfQ3mYG0IROYkM/LlEpngsmbKIcaL@FQcdIWCTl7ivBe/NXGZayVXJbtM9Q7m1FcXOKl2xLQ6zv23uWyueptYMWvjHAg6yXpipVdT08VUOr1ipRIrFk71jx6hOeduBSSJRha0oxEAKStmsgr0DJJHbcWqrmibiZV2rZCiFOAF/ewWEnzt5rK3K9pdbuURzNQZCHH44E2suHQPYD6bVe@gfDhCVnIZoJlbvDaNXjOB2a8Y6TSWIbvSwAJ8nbs4TRPPvjjNkeWoKgTRXLcvhtsUV/V7Yua9GrwBRbDoaGDsBWTsYr9xQwIHVzgX58UtkD14xt/BIxyM9pPpbljyj07GPJyxCH4Xpyua@K2L/CJGaMBRAhoRvRktmQRm8g//EFPXWDSxsrVWtNPxUr4KP2q1xErsk5WLwmqMxR6Dpp5LRZ3o7cVu@ZrpncLaG0U51zrZN5fHV8fHXyQvEvHYztFXUXUVQNfZBn0f@llnhQUf9nGfWCyVi8RyKfXRei736tUrEHfhc17P1sNQ2cvkuRK/PE@sg6e@vp7KrJVTmcfxBhUlmSgUkqfMMHLswhi47TZ87R693yUR4x@2tYV5gQP@mQjrjzo8LCgMBxGhMq2M@gBc5VorxdjFuqal0quFx1Y1W8gX/vrPl@8yt8eNzb/@jX5OX8bHET5@dPcM3adq6ZPl5U@ePFldzUDjcffx946/3N7eXt3NlI7PS1urSn5586/@cnm5UNgs5JYvXVe9jJ9ffREt5Fej2b/@4/jx8Xcbrov9h58iU8GJv2X4qqxUYlfsLXyuOgz/yf22HXJr6G523uIECcJyjZhNPF4qxk@/imN138ZUVY2N6a9BzbDM1PrW@n/9ydGbmBerF3IvHXh6sTextXKMO8EBvqL0XcfqsU0EW7uLjXO1Wg2c6//1P0D6@meAB2PGm/BTL0lca@NYXalRknex@ho41EIB8v2/vv/9SKw@QkKoH@yzQr2Q4rSilh@pj/w@uoip5dWjxxAsPxQ8kh9SdFW1cCH7M9Td2LV@cA8qD/3K7FCY3@@SMmJMUAM5HgoH5Y7t4edv/o@/@enf/IT@fkrf/4SvUllbfvxqlzEdZmD8VCqP/drl2Ho5atswyqvgO/TDT7IKfLIN6a@iVxE1i5VrmQYvlU/CsZBjqh38XyaaxPd/JFwkJpd/lXN2GeqCaB35kyzrM4s94x/Lgn/4Si@GYAC4LBYUWrZtLGhSP3M2HSY7w/cwyQvYx8BFYl9D44/mfFg9CGdUBV5qcjwL1SyoG5LDFnyW4Y/@4eN78XeZQkQwgcx@ltm3/0Ri57Hzy8unFv413@Df4Vv8e@Ph31kL/07e4N/ZW/w78fDv2MW/Z038C/PySEwBzpBOn4DIKIj2IZ8X8M1mG8LnE28sEvulfliExW7hc5lW7u7Os1@lq1XxD5JU1ffhh7ugTJd3irL5VT2dPqeynddFITeVyzrjRabfbOOrTcCb3jzfrNk79M026vBR4qt2fM1@fPlV/XxzEodA8/hxGgftY8BTX7lkIMPX6@xu865@d755d7e5Cf@b9HsnnhB6tznzT4/gU10A5H/uLpGBXpzn6he5izr/XII/m6tjSDZ3AY46PBsAeH4eid0iubDzS7odqaacq2ulS4XRkEhVMK7lMlZRU4VirjT6ZG2vEIkVotFcCqPe4cQE4sVGJIZC@gaX1Tco4NX7b/43/F68/@bfgReKhm8nw9hIrMYYCDkrW3kzf51Xr9QrcBgsDzJmL99T28jU8zrLj/Njlu/bahtcOvzlwWXkOyzfZXkrb6kqRILDY3kPXR14dOGvA1gc@DPyeUSev2aQi4lTBd2cSs93DZa8iJyz6CsdpJOsGs/m49m1eNy4LK0N3kQz8cbFefyyGsu5Fxc5LrexwmqVrsy9u2ONxt7z3UYjh6R88cw@Cv6Pjvph773//SP72ZHdt@H/6OjoGXRc@nFaeQyfWj29KR5bsXp166KiID1KyozlNrcu6kUF3WtpoLIChqU/8hNghGd9@SICSu3LlzfVly/x/@a6elMlh@8FR6PqAwgw7oBAHgAIXlar5EA3fK4JK/nQefPywndxR@7lDQS9ZCBm@/@5Cd8v4d/4f9f/sxcscX6ZhHFwe7eZoE8S/5LJ27vbO/FbTyYSwpPYhD8MAD8mub2ro5OAbsF1nkheJu/ueBj8JpKbHGEd89isU@IAEAZ9jOd6EQdJAxTDhFjQurgY5fPJahNCfNO29o7WRpJV2jWy0sT1LFCG1FSSQEqr1eqqcK@Xq9WycKtra9VqyofKg0c4AUh3tVYVR1M1NkhiGfgYS@TRZkbX0sejleijRwnxIoOtwQC0W3Uj/@6dH9RotA2n0cDw4rt30UYU943UNkrgz5ffvYNxHk@C3vvcFiuWG6DFqrlCkENPczXPcxJvjUEmihso3WiSLo7N5xEUU7PS5ubaar2@tgrutXIyWY2u8C0niW56Q03ereSivB6gj8ZjIkotrycp9C6O8Sy2ybbqQO8uftjtXYyam62WkonmWE/eQogMUzc2eCBbXUuU0xvir7acZPUUE3/n5@fF9GpqPfX48vJySmBBnlS91WrqXe1Wq6Cx5K7aEneQ4xZ57dGj4ga0TjlfvYg0GrvbZ9sNfH0ZrgLDTMAwkLhbBFf4Bk78nCxbpY3Lc6zR5UU8Xqk@5j1cLrFYvCrglDgwSlbeoIrHQH02Ong2ZkRYp76p2ICp60WYYiID2o2znmdtXNB0mN3pLEMg9A1r4tqzq5umvLT9xnbM9o3R1pcjsePD7Z29s0xhE2arwv72TqZw@uJJTEVvKfBTdBH9J3vbu0cvIMHx4d726d6nB5/vvTiGcDfy@q2m65o@1PWbxnB48wbv9dYb@gBCg09Dbxmu9vq1NqAPq3K@dnPz/mc/fP@z/@79H/34/R/98P0f/fTn3/z0h/D9U/j@mD9//O83Svj782/@5Z@8/8M/gsD/BN//CN8///k3v/d9/iX/X8D3P4fC/kJ8Q3D8yyqxego/QAjlQjmdgokjtbEBxEChmxHI67d@/s1P/vjn3/z278P3X4vv789@f@fP539/@oPFX0z3kz@5H@bH/wG@/yvHJWF//Ic8DJ8z8H/I4X7799//7v/O//9K/KHzj97/7l/gj/D8D7//V//5/W/8n4VC@a/@7fsf/vj9D37y/ge/8f4HP3r/g39eeP97/1bNh3/@BEju7/7sZ/j/kz/7u//4M/z/X/7N3/3Z//h3v/U/k@MPuOP//tf/nv/@7W/88G9/8K/@9je@WfD7w3t/v3lA@De/gpCHl/MheB5Sr48N@eZblecXaY0gF6ABugydFUCOezLWQcOO5Fle/MCA@em/eP97vwl0@LsACb7/Hnzwzz0Q9SPyfPHFRFya9HAl/cUXoNh8IRScL8JAP2LsXQ5kzvzjdwDwBcXyD/OhINP/CaEAjAkoCTaROYHgrj8e/PNv/tUfY7ifEkN/M4wvL0NDsCsI/E5W8Uc48PxqhGF/hEP3/c@@//6P//n7n/3B@5/9FvJtZXUjs51R1A8Y/wCw9AA4BFx7CBwAqqjcgBa6HCmAY3kTjVURNf3qFXTCMrhApUhFSkXwRdQ6uVV0Q0LQWVPcRpRG6xB8R5HVDfCh1SgNE2aaR6Uh6kkaX/qbjoxqEEeg@LZghs56Gc0AqP7WAC8m4mkyjTKI6Wz0hLBAylr6hDVStRFPmMaAOmFgWCAMOomqhWi6XNuFDGujXYa4EHk68gqer2r1cm1UR3RfUxEAR/oJZAlQ@DLi9Kj@NfhrhBPgI6Pdr6Eo5Vo6XS9DSI2qSrllGpSnWqLKUd3TjOqN4Yzhzrutx4x9ElXLUa6fQ1MyAY2/6QB6i8xUWxB/kU6J6tC/dNI3hemhn0bUPjyMx29hMKUXAIBXUXDDFnwVBUvzGKJHHFWasoVHmmOAlksLA58fQMJEOpKm/k2TB/KHMnzMZ5NPpIgOq7OysgKuzXq0GG0cgXbEnKuK62kOrimRbFdh0bWNKAbjBhi@q2/lmJSo1G4KflX431umnaxUk2oqshJH5TrOZE5Kumiv2jFeCVlD8qWoAmkCZJ9ADH4fPwY3tBA9g7BILEjHxXdaPgS5e5UlIwl6u0uSNHgdBRYWeeZ2n9gjkLEz0WhGXcNlgSTX7yNf2pVK7Wt1dT0CT/IP8b0y4g0n0Fn4dt3s5iY2ev1WIVMDOkGIW4vU62L9k6mR@uneGYCfHTG1kM8ykMhvV9cLq6XVUqG4tlZaL6iraxura6VyEVjZWr5UKKgbq6sb5Y31O6rLY@AGmUqqWdqs/7OZz3/zz@Z95ofiJ1L/go2yZC@9i9TNGt9@t4LroNGLfLRKJg9quZXzfAb/CsUi/EIZM2pp/XJ52bxVsMoXtOfrFleaoZiRW2WE9tkl@LDIUoQtQRh8IBNcCmJi8f7gqCoWavHdcHyxNqqWgHiSkQsgHo4OevH29jb0jcSWv/c9j9XrIIQrB/uRGBB9z3//vGK0s70svdGtPXR0iu0ytnvw@cHpwdHz7O7BKQjGX7JCMZ@NxO7u7jq@PZ28Ojs6OqJUoOYUVXTdtdhwOKTYJvjvRlpkEP5U4RtB0noEbPORyp2ltcCZR@emOIxaj9BS2jl062UEX8lzfhnZzPmRZ3g2@Dk0DxCUxQ5xM6lnszObb1p8orcWQOz0@MuldxwbNItvD/NEs6541K7BDyP6UU81vF7Q7RtebwHEi0EfD/Hozq8Mw16/CQVEozoHeAI/jmnb8wDW2YvjBbV85t8hgKvWdIkAgJ8cfPr0LPQ829veeRpZY0@Onu9OPUoCqMQO9/bPfO86j5VJSz6KL/cOD6e94gFcqkqq5DIrrWcywOzhB58Z@tAzu/KVBFGz97wTZSVXL1cdHRT8mvq1sumtsBe1J1@nnw/75eKGulECAoBad3XQem2jDXWPaZ527Ky47PgQdeBaXTNv79jqOujCnw9ZuR55hlvmNlR@9MNwI09BF@3jy2zwxVVeBE8rtvGFtWhDaOKbY4cDtjAQHhiETsfo9oAZ39gSINLUNAbfj/1A@rAaCo10b4DH86CwmRhzDjiu0xodlo9kycZZ2CiXyhvFQjlT3iivltS1UimjFjLqenl9AxhjXi2ra@XShpopr24UV4FzQ2xpYz0SA4ZmdHI5mJXUaBSeFUBrtfCO8U28rN3O9uqRGLfcsLf4SvSY5vuHLKpDmii@Ccj1aENwyqhFC6u4W7@oMsCosRaL7e/v5Pf3o9En6EFb7k4@Gm2jp1TO59efRKM6xezA7FKIRm2eBqIAzOOefP7JTjQ65Ajw4oNotIeevTUUl6NRAz072/v7mM9r9BQwPYBd8RjuMaVnHcAs9BSLJG9Ho298dAC3zTNapZLuoQfzxJh9HrMDcdHop7I8@TxgOOFwHMNTWdft7Wj0gHu2tzHmM6p4iRf1O@jZpk806oAHiDAa7YKj6@i6FY02wYmkGI22wNUaaxCG97njQXjL06LRMW8gbKJodETQWusqCnKhCMdsnj59qvW8tt7ln7HDny0oGsQYo@HefvPTT5vdbtMZb@99eoIxn332VHs9HjrNblMkazbgY0MaiLnqj6c/UMaDRkMz58Z8B2KsqZjGuKFj2RraGyiT@HQxk37jM4j5DGLmre1xbPDpA2gTP0/68HyiNSlGfiiGnqNmM1pFQvXGAx2NWzhm6I3Wmb7Wcuwq@ke15Xginhmfr@UvqxTM@onkbb56h7GdBL1NDflg8nZ8PqrlL0FXWC@IEwWJ6MWoUDKimeX@FjC0yrK2pRZW06MKXkdpd@IsrqhbCfVR6m3ieXKrUFytRC@2tpTouXq5VVDLlbX1r1LDaDRZwd@t4nrlbSIfzzOGP8nz9cut9VIoxfp6WssVKuvryeodtIQHk1Fz6OmNRiJxo2tXySSWFYUYKD9/cfeYqmhUO4lRZlTjhWLjZHVUU4Exe0OYhPIzuNp47n@IryziGLuAbrSVr6BhMRFVN8pRyD@XSyIvQu4Bz1cv5aqB/wg5Jpz8k2UVhb/tTC2vJbO4Pb1hdxr0Jhj2KgyJsmvkJR4joSOkcssXSfluJXKGoi69H53hjSNNfMEindoFTYvfXsG4IUFd34hE6kLYO@bvU6gKL94SkN3HN@naThbfAOlNxPAz7DKInY5BJOhnD46yLyxX6/hYzvSRl32q456ulgzb4ec8s3sjfIW4YVvVW@WlckeHi/FkKF6aAFOfVquDS2uzBOXOtOQN1atRr9catb7eH3hjUCmoLep@YphI2RPGIfGQidxn36g9germqxZeH6Sjd2UUG0XqbbwM4Untye2wUgHYu6peo3cER2N4MGfLqg2pPse6g2dCDo5WOkzHwxet3quLPQTcgaa9vVPqDrOqfikOXN4@/jZ/KtAtFkhENGr5u2q3do7h7/BnU4lGLxXl/N1lpA5DqjqOaTV32ORvzMo3QRdZq44gTF1frfZYs9b8alR1agOQoFnVhMYKaQZMqxL8OxNmx0a2URsF1S7WzgvFAm7pyRTyG5mCClMiTJUADd918K/CV4UvxKuoPyTMRJSxaCY/ymfVjKqrGc/es6CV85UKNjZ0E3nhqSXThZSZaNtM21So02CEVqmIWqbHBkaml4BUJ7pmcvCkklDebK2lV1eTyeobKJ2zkmhnnyS3VqvtxBPWSEIATOzwLbC11WqnlvgqWU0sJ2uu/qYa7vJEMlLHQU41HixD4wqlyB32z/NseU3N3CoN5c7UXG9FXS9Uzocr54oK1cu/625Gv1ePXkLb37EI/IVXGkBoqEKYHNJczAgEhSBsgAKiqUNXqRuFqgCJDAR7SUQT@MpUvmUwEY@vF@LxZLyK6vcyhAv2RLwkDowt/kjdioKgEq1ENwqga4XY0kwR@KLTGqhBd5G24Q7Y6kYkdhu5u73bDG9U@w4bj7W0Ir2PGOumVyIsRyuo2UaMLZNLydbJRrJd2@6ebFcF9PZOJFahvT3B/gx2IY5XKrnlj122TW/Wv@LPC9xyALlG6LqLc3Yp1qkLRahzO@SH@rm3Ed6qfCU@t5mu5y4i0SiNVL5oVS4leUnZ1zG6FJrt3MqXgVeeoSbLElqFj8Dzy@TXzw3ztlxU6qTvJVjs6zS0CG5Tque@jgFDv6OGFnuEbm8Ht7egYd7hkeFCsRSJWbbcPgRapAecDmaCUimKFgmdDU43vlr/qvzVsxdHL4722eN8pVwph3WBi8eZjBpX45vsMQigxske6BnvmF1Sv7Y@ox1SsWqsMogXV@PFiWS12Ki2KpcbE2q9rqibBbYFtMoqwG866pqSf1fnhFeniLUCxLz/zd9fHW2WwV8AIa8CbVpKF@p1NVVIxgbvv/l3eBTndu/z7UMWxwr@/V/@cWH97//y39BSWPyuyiu9HgNIdKpr67HLGC/C6jpLgofW0wpqrJ4T4eq6moy5CvdB8Uox9524FCFRyJchbueI@6Jr0GqxjVgkVn726h1jm6Dw1dvdrlEgVy43oUStVEBxgn/2NVpxvlaWXwEvcd2VHKRnGwgsLQ@per2eQhsti9fTeHqsUCKL9/ld9ZJbBlCDSFn0p7sp/NO/8gNSrgt@6QNvalNnpbrKQOXI5d7/5u8VCmt//5e/c5F813jX@C6w1I2NjTW1EPuH2U8utRRhqaVtFudXLfIZG29Z9k/WxSdeuYpWtNSSsnt6tPOdvTOcsnULbxNhO0fPsxh1OtBbwdHIlqlrjjnmJxI7Y4TCmf5s55jZDnuxe0xpXtKhWAola5jIZeWgXRFvestcMzVbxOXjUi6/mlNLDCSy/HqlsMY0YG8uXoIhXCuYlFG1duzBmKuLiZ0kJV7aRhiMOzRAd3f1Cvv0@JBSEPdILe3uPTtiR88Pv8zKUB5@9vTglJ0e7Z@93D7Zg3o82ztl0e1TdnAaZS8Pzp4evThj28@/ZBB9sv387GDvFBHkIsgZUZ7lDearbmzTHbs5FHZd0t8mgl27daV7k@GaM9ByeJX4ZLCFbyLT8Z09k@FDywDlMKwanm4vcVmRIXqt3XYieBrXaLElVAuXUiBf4GHgXt5dZ6XhF2/zTmmZtVafx9dZK//cKm6uMzMv/pi52i@esOXl5Qsr6s8r4Wr4mmk4CA@eQFhQpoPv7S0l1lZZCvTRwmoyiHl@dLyUl76llydnS6ofd7K7VPA9B/tLRd@zB75V37f/cnep5PuebH9naS1I9nxnad337e7tLJV9HxDp0kaA8/nukpqPyMa6Bhlwid69m9g/ONxjKQBKVidi0SiJjqlgaIgESG38ahRscpZK3fTsDKk6zfEUdFv/ELQEn4BaQsHxHNv1MsNS9gB@QCQFYEhGp1u4kuR0WxmBFW/eg0knchtZwgotYYUAfgkP5SMcW66xQpJB9FJHaFL8Bp8Mi75w6ejtJy7bRHWgDsSQoav86Ag2pNDFm8MjS3cCZaJDhtsObe0nUBVKGnWiySSe23z@4vCQZzYgeTcRJUjGhd85OO0BYIMqwi9WHUJ55/Buob7AtloSsgq@3TxyN9GbkenexKaAei4ttQDBZOtea2aGobSWwb0ViBc9/EgOAEM0uPPg4gdWE4kW1rWrey0qUBIbc@9on9cQd2fU2GQvJxlmSi1F0fywz7t3TPouvEmvM@m14hy3QM6LxfHxktYQNolhS/KkMEHQrQiUcgkpJp2G1FAdigvVawkaHb78EgVZyjpklI@zR4@oHJvg24hTFpguTTkyBUEQgWgwaj5E5hdtmYqbXMql6OwZ7oii26BxHuG3eDfH/gUwwFmnCzrVq/4o9LtzyQJtuTrFkEVUp419De5ioQF@ZI9AyRnWhGGSYTJSXcNI1BYzTM@wDgRP8dSGYQHl6k7AEyUpwGCk3n@@y3uI33ZE4TyAagx8r0IdBsziEQ5fIvSlpaaja1dVCQX8kKCAbpFoEtgQHO7@dCe7lCzFxwuSJaZ@SMqD/YqkI54ayEFQGjUrXlDBaUVUlwLrAdAMfoEMx28N0HOS5MjSaQHhU5kA25uEUxQOdyfp8gOV2JuuxfJH1wLZ8sJa7D2wGr9YLWBaC0gEagEsPgF40wBNP5O9WZiHAuZCQkG1@XYoYAINaAnG@ASCB6SHKTdIr3x8epikK9NDGcYt9CDnCjzJpLc16W1PenH4QojGNjdZYRV0nia61DVw4UUFrAyONueVkwk7k14yJtWYLtN0fA7McwCaQ1bJwZAAZ5kxcpCsi68n0vr4wrwa295vHDzfO5uMRXxZtyEK3vNsy6Q8kpNgokAY7ybQk/RLlOhgI3B5M3HM88hQezZOz072tp9loHxJthmMgGkZAH7ESJiowZ3MAUItvQXzcTvDEqfbLJVkj7BkGSZsEOh5cBam7eqAamGO7eGgQFnlOYjvnxxJMRyRkTlZRRMskWTvLi5gSs2vM7U/eFfsF631YpuNi@so7HI8vgwiuLxkMM/50OTCBkK2@dWylbmZvc7n2apTZJ7eA4l7lHdm8VO97nBuo2lRngwf2KSUuVWGd0oibxGXz8C8OCna3C9F0tyIdIChOIwhDKdzMj@mST5H8qRYKWDxsrT1jy3LhyTaybIovCyblOlsGYT2GjkLG5pxZVHctjFsmgbqofRmanaAtvaxvHwpw/o2dJqBrpY9oCcaqYRdHXyubcIv3RaGy790ybc@Gpi2gffa4R07uD7vBJfuZiNHFuuDnkv2Zm7@NvBqOnFena7l4TcA0nnZyFKrNfFO8tCryl@BljSwugpQd8foMkVpdUyt64LDbJPrVeTUv5sEczANDVqQslAPG5qaLwl9m@4oxsLh276Pn3/K8J5X1O2l8UkzDW9MG4JRyKJNwTreiewa1zqwHbzFSW9nI1yNfZBqFw5Dc9ZkGJ0ZnlJ4NdfVnSmtdsATSvLJpR7jbuvHqZygGzwB3NCcpuHhyzYa3Mbc4DlKQX4wqVDRVhFBdbg9hJMdnbbnzr42Qt9UKmwxMqEFC6ioJECOWl@XKlQqNSCUJEwy7glhTg0W4zb63V8W6gncbUOfwGtDWw2hrWiUzTCiT1zS3Hwg4DvEgfa@ODhriKu@uN7kL1vdo0aGWrkqfYMqr0Go/KLks7omsk0oPt4Xwq/shKpe25yWo6TMoc4HvQ3/IRWS3iqFRUdsA5piz1cvuVqUJ31ENrif5hGnhEehUj0KGnRJzBI@DTwwHdc6OchsfRFxx9F1AiAVVVrRpzSYXzLtLeiZpqlZV@iqcv2fpVynFeosusQoVA/UA/26CKWQL1xCvSGpr9sHBY06frcQgNDyZTe/sHA4kxER0/Ae9rNGkRzzEBew9PFu2FYiiE5JOYLXLSlz4vBTWR0B17Y7aC6wnTHPCC9gSFSrAILCB/EE3ZIqeKjWtaA1EB1JKqFSAN1WZRDuS9ODcmbY/aXlWS0TOZBYM7@oXMJBqHO/WJc8q8W8ENo7Ga7MRNKgcaRcBE6Y2j2QxE29IygOpjGiEa5yz7QKF199KmK8nc7zl/DPtsKeCrdG4IDS0QSELCSJwxivbZgqnF9oBK37QwezCkiPOgrNUtiFBtEiM0BiwHBmpNMT/RRCfm5gu6ksTa2dmBMLbMivkWh60fYEQ4I@9Aa3L7AOF0t5W0emmgg0CDTQyFKD16fGY7k@DiThv/oHCZxTJh/LokGr0i8Hoe@mmKBRfK56N2sgpB0CuufYNwNjpJsJYJgNvMJswCBIyGGDAXcQhC@TQTB2NpVd8Kvl5QSkOie4XPmSPWIJdXMzsa4kKOiTcjLpD0aRvBBKHkoMTLpeZ4lCKlGUiVcxMaAsTiJYnY@gwBGsphKqRFAQCNQSYOAiBiH5BFQyotpJxOUQYh/v5SQMXoQ2J/dUIa1ebm6WUXENBU4lLswveqqYLkBijnopPRnD0fKIUPjlZI0AebEQmkdCKFbTRUDBs05PRgS5TkX4mYbzXL2cOzn90oQXaXyWkw8lx/uYdee8jPVFSuWWtgED98BzRCDeiTmgmzGDME7SKSRzkBFoSEJuPR1XgjL8ZlQxaUH7VadmxZDFlyCQDVAjSDxGhr2@b65rfvxkh8AdutWG1xnU1QwrgxoCHAU4RhkSAwuhNjC6jVZ/4MPBVFxOcjMWn8Aok@c23nR9DdJ9m8R@mROxMd58eMkV4BM3U9Icwts3AQkahwdP8PH53gmaAQ6efwpduIT1yLDgV1ZzmWP0q7ijWfxSfsMzoAjA27hCI@rKu2oyfwyU@QtsErmAn8bOE1LtEILxxEI6JLowvIZhC2y8KSUd6R61I13e6AOUk1XQM9iNzjQTm2PML50v8zseaSWPUlNTgcNPKAqILYRtdnay/fx0/@jkGbXccWP78PjpNmIGBbOlOW1AP@hpOEAsSzf5pOq3ZwSn3y6@OgbrpDXlrWX8pToIy6@z5Y0HgA2KaVDodImwvpzoZ@B58LwExFF8aBAqGm19MAc3KuQ@mKiMOwch70VeajEVijLNmwlpwpudCSUfrSOno7a0ddeKe0DYHl0lZ3F@kpP4noCWSVfa0shFOapL9OLwOzyLBbrYH@nIHQ7QIqa3o@Hm11ot3aUNaUHrA0rd7FAmgrOEGgpC5tc@4B/c4O7PvQIH3WtMk27el3sDMXdSWATpkbfdt5JxQwISxyJlpFspVpJYJHLm7xmYEB2NSZFxUWY8t9c8t9eQG2e47PW0QGZcnr@eEMTmNY8hm@c1l42lZMbFE98@Rj3XgUHv9nCvONlCONehDsNuoq2S9niC1z2SXfZIjuJgJM4X7u4XykTDTkpkYsIJ5k@hMLfb0GyJGdsGmeNJ@xo62P/cY@k36KGZkq/eSBWD4IlSGiBOSzjJPnFhaCFlICbghrQEcC6yu6RJxceXEAiZIsuTDMkatLQsrAKGBdwiWHETdSVR0naFohgKRLYqZmGnLQc5QQaTmdOeXqVCIAzlq6iBqZWvTfKMyuikO5FrhBopJJBZKYLLqooCCZLcrkEyDbBbrAMVz/DmV6M8Ww1ROSmTGdysj6xOuFXOChD0Heg9ECozr86td6gecoUPEydDFctXhVlYblN4ccyKarEY2tNw9PI5W1sLtjzgeRO2WsgH@yjw5Alb24h8KztZYE/g9IgDR3QokhXSDKruIAvqpgmDmD/aBk79WDauFo/4Y1z1hasU12BdwY7F1OCyPr5tpanjW0XwDeEeU0dqNrIETPEs9L4aOXkDYHeoOfgOLb5wjIzcpTfqUYaUkF575bj8XTb0Nhfg@PSORXfo6NwADCFtu0Wvg0EclA56etinLcIZFBiudQf3Nhme2L20RDxHkANnDXVOBDJQMoe6pA3ehIIl0IhGIwtvRpqWsfW46UW4CiSunB3mqZRnhypNafLmdywANa8gFWpj7o4siQaemWZIH0@JG0jlkPSBA9Y/zzQ4O8lw5VTq4QINn2NmNX/jco4xhqirFZ6DRthiEhXV6TIpF/aIA8h1nZa0Q3AgeowuaXoiXFwbxRbEd8EY3BbOiEeQFEGzFE0pDlKd1rqSR5Aoesl/9wXRcw1GXxICKDOxCuiv@QoIJPkkhxALvtMQOD45xCiMA0rBB2pKbDckCMThL@Ih@yYKkVo4upNCL0AEXK8lsYuXny@0za@FGKOUKV9nmy4pRSVDY3k@GK@yAMPahcCgUMSPUv4eSg724jhYzJOAVHoySN1X@IncHlp4kd0M0ERLPLDofkPcCVvdPKSQuG9f83deiYUzKWaG@ocLSdCJghCIZmncC1OFaAPJFXjpmqEUXGaWaSQnoRixk2GW5Qgo35EqyD0OkqH7Zs5gs8K8inJKllWV1aQepPdPmMaApsbJuophEa6ros5Wdj1UWbl1YqKyIpGs5@ymNQscHXzDGG0qwwklKrZjRD9pZ9gnbVwMESHhOUq2xjz@N7mBIzQgv6oFI9Kvn19W2gnge/hYFWuHyNrD9I7pEG9eDnJ8AQFNASqC21ZVvmiFp1paEuIMCD0T6QpJYXb2yVmi6HSAX@NmODo5fFiQmAKKISw19jXHQ1MQva4sBCzB3hGfxwIkfVh8CUsYNkRFgjNPDFJJHRiRTov5rDZhDQ52hSwkxDAWwTtD@y7uTU88ZbYUY4zj0@R8HDKJmO6D8V8NF2S8sCDYHLRGJOY6f82I7/O6@0VXRgPZbSAkN5C7BgX4eSMEMSG/lfJSDkgMAnnB1w64PhCWDYSgLYVBNGzhWwETA77fI8Mg94XwwbbJN3yBr9VzMCVtawwno/1zYYbES1gIqUWDkBIzW0zqHWrRAe@TyXJTR5IhxMfOq/FocI7IcgUFlwG5M63O1GoCHaOdG2SNq/IdjSTK4ikb0lPDWxqx41NYeVyyDPSsAe54kLsdCIXRH5g6f0ehetjYPjoI3lgp3tiiuzYGuVnb6eZujCsjxwEjp2IvvqIPcZzjznse09h7AVMZ7qL3suxU55sVdPFmwlekTurD5CtMhNv6LQDudEDitfAFQvKFVgKBmw0XFqI1l7@ec2zbzaD0Gr6wGHRSXoAMld2FwnehYYZNer1MS/NcfaznMGGuacJPX8Nz/jlQyXNYw9yRpR9C6lN8/2P2tXatRXZDBaNXOk3lSgdvIgrajigG31jMd4@gDcGjl7Y0begbGLk67ZQQSgKd37Mtc8ws3NfUpXdAM3qNgXxvJb74EF/gIxZ1aMsDf1/kan5jjZi9K2Y4SofzdzYLcaVkhN93X2HipYpVoGbUdXjyiT0tU3sy@MCc3ETB9fzJsBaeOPjwPg1/i0cuF0prWw/Z9zFvjwcdaoBmX7TzI5dD8@jAxJce3mh0wwLbWV3Pr1UYf7sqkSGOFnorRSCx66MB3hqPGwNwHpdpTf1aN1kRu/Fzwx0C4Kk3hCpFYgNH6/Y1CZgoVhhmEzp4QPr1xDalIMq2zcmQjoYTRqBR03uqmBpgo3fbiVkFG1MEi3lBTwLXgp8t1mhYtj1gFXC08aWSNBnga0JkCrzTXss0MYGWrCeayS14VuAJRadT/TCOcfDX/E35uJ/INtg5DPNLJhcootUI1QKGfo2XvirT48yBYKEVHZiw@aoGzAgp1hDKKLcSADTOYQkO53K7Jy2eS5C2fXCEVhvKEEbsIOHHYBX5EatkdeGekhQL7SkBloCb6JEwaV9/LictI/FtvP9fep7EeSxZjRLcHZiI@KyX8ptD7l/o8N0nm3TQgdGBR2rOJI5ASqxW2Z0ExD0gKOHgzhIlLncOoITp4NpMsCMFmj4qtbD70IYKUPwAJHUckhnOS6FqUKa06Hjn71uZjlYv5RoWhNfyVdka/HUhfv8Hi1mPeG8uUcWX6eUjt0yepm/xhRhaJRELTBNlxclL0AhRB8clpvgEpwcKmKQGYU0ko2nGN6jygnKbKzALlDkVmlIybMS6aH3n6lOGjYUXrxGJ8EsD8plxTa36Nwvo1rB/i8pIhicZDjIIfMd04PbVCP4Kjc7hmfujG2YJYuvIyOmFdxR0LsPRtHGbzzD1rko5t@h@Tc7iQY6Ypf25e7EuLMRXOQdVhP4v@TRR@aQdzfD8cMmAHKp0FC4zQW68Ef1Sj8b2VWKUGQPrYIkR7e4krQPdwjhP3nEoijZeinUawWDQDtvQcN2xgW2XkMcqWGNUAwWpMa6hDY8fakCBlw8L2hWL8BUGgIqCgKChMinsUjw1M7C@UTqN8aDUTcYPB3R2VqaficfeI/w8fRj/XXDyh9qhMco0xkm5LwVSNMYpagJ/e8rdTHWpeL9AfWfKO1Xfmfbw67ugPfz6zrbnt6qvbzH@gioCUww9UMdBlX0LNGp83ZAM5HaKLYaB@WCG2v1yOvVwgNfaTaWm631mU9uDge3iHRPzS8DznFMIig@FQ55bPI8KuEFBznHzkVrOw9DDG1vcCB/ijo3yYoLceN0xn79AnjS5bVvM0RSAmDfIou97lSk/ZJAUU0k4SLJEv36YFeepXJwAse2K9hfXWCirql9wqijXwRgl9mufZNwbwhGqOm1fhNLIJNhQSTYvyRDlDkw3nQTD5icRrS7442QqbHU2N5XsREwtdldKSYjYTvSAa0mB1B0NrTU1iDsDuYbkCV@P9e29o7QkcN4ZZOmNp@UsDarYAX8V@Y54Ze@xsE7hO3fpJeOOPez2GO5@RxmQvxUXE3RslO5RugSpHm@5HgL5tCtyW1wiqL5vP86xFwMGSv6BfBf8s2O2g4J/k17mzm0BidA0IXZYLS1J2WkpMGkvEaf3gS@5oY9bHILsqc9CBdhFeoAiPENLHGR/QuQ0J2M5iSmqL4FENc/D60xQshavs8fqB8kGuAwTJEQJQB5cIGFlyQedX1hOxqHSUunCxT0EUplX2vzcQtKZhOlCNnU09eXvKRy3Ik7bbqA4mDuWZlf/FfSfnytfvQa9/wOkCZlKqswQnA5KLm6OBmEHz@b38ep2fA8xp1TQwAHlc3xjsGmOM3Mx36A9jkaXdgO6F6nKCJfOiuL0QJ@9xo1Gc1PTiltPg66iowOICEpAopV8QyPioTd4s2ekjvqJuQLskiiHh2l5MewWrjLLxLMtgbcz6m0XRVYNaYXKmcDjDWK4ylXCtoFvhMOa@6xXFofs0aQt9owWP5Wxc4xFcfQ3Q8PhyjaWJgt9Sft@gBR2ejq@PxVg8ea5ALtiWAo0m@Updoe5b4aagyYH22HpuBsRPJ7PNCdiJ860HCUYVHUCmCivNiuEhIBR/MTzbVNkJe11aKqRPI826@BtR3FXXEEkbEbYtmHbD1pNsgz4lW@QgenZ5LwYWojwhNTvDOsMTeTF9iCLccgJJysb9qFg2Vyu8ZNZE9UMeSaAOGOdjA1hFNtQHB9DgqZxMRNzTvNh8I0ZaMxqAbDCoX0dK9S@fqNBU06028TyDh0KCuwXEE328wTSmythOrjXwtGFCoFp8skMZTKLlqbiWayWbSlhzBxsFjHAIVjyof1X@0fqP4YCkIW8BxjMYICvdJXvVaeiC@0TRjrVEglZVAX4QH9oepql20PXHP@qCSGyRDdDC9kZgsbk/VJ4J8VxVMO4dpbDG07YQe6Itrvh3gRU1IF5Fw4rGBM9E6wGO65vi3mWmeIYjJuRd6fhMlHiDOMORRxOjnJPwFQMzE4MLT24TcCjM14Zvm0AWCcdF7O8LKWTG@y0ljckJtqzcXMFf9tuBrc69IGNQDh1CTJsrAsitwe6wzMDahvbQybnZ88OnV8EBhkcIDQgUzH1EX7kzVgtpHs@kQAexB1Cxd8/HkoD7BcKDuDBW@/59NbUhY0CJze@ukVvj4UcKFt4Im6Dn4ELMvzWufFVOLT5YpaIeypdPhulq2FCVjK@zz6xLPT7pFT0p/Y/kcgsbV0SlhOU2NuPKwm0q2LWLCcVWKNKGy0SRg13amziCQsYlwB6blwu13Cthe/aINsZ9uINEIiuOa0eVAn6y0CC8Rxqp7bRpmYDHQ7N3v79DC4D9Hj3W5IL0Naw39TxDSTUXv4xTVr3QCM5gCQC1EnKOTh6aRCHM9JAzxe41ZPsx@2kP7Z4VqSXoPIDgL4dCWdQUSayX4qGQX@ws8lvnU5CeNEUUsBmQf@5CFTUS3nJxkxU4VJex@GrfIXqNEb1HozJwHg2dSQMDV5eaIvTje1c8ZUjNLsR5/c0g@zeuBbINyxjImnRw0V@N4jjKxnSOBfc1UTjGSeWnuZ92MgrqckDpmjyAz384FTQwHwNrxpsWvZ3I@c5bQELa3ELVE5E4c4onpavXHLG7hOPXHPlNkR@NigfProl2roWHgq8r4Upk59rc8yOkK4maENACopAaFlyNL8Lk6TMQyE0BMULz3UcKny6JsGq4riTEg65Q/Wfl1M2n6AV3arn5Wjk9FGrceoI8vA3CbdCW3VT8ngD30820fxY5XHNv5Xm27UbcQxuTq2ykdjfRSetRnyH19KU/s14jc9RJF1aGn9M61Bb@NvEA5t8lKhZDAPSO/zNgAVOG1NanmSMHT705xxVEZs8@R0uML0zvCFGHN8Ab9gY7npJf7leDFDXy7oe0U5oplc49wH6njfuNNO1YZLkkpo5FqPepfXCj1uJkSOQZy/GXXPYwaLgSj@kCQ6ozJ5OWe74LIe25vIFf95SBE77DoeIg4//ZGi3oLwlhJ9aASg6siJW@EXCc2kTR/RiG3VH2Mh4DViqIbIVdRDloUrQgvdBcPUcaVWfOnoXHicGlqjtxlFe8le@s5Fdbkw8Pjp4frZ30jjZ@3zv5HSPUtJGfv9A8XCQI0uZe4M3FlgCb9wN33WXjbx0DJjHccahy@NQAz9t2Z7H9kHd1UEdv9IgpTbUIwvX3AuHi@NeuLpT4enPuDBPh@9pp7Fr4BGhIW5VgvrdcAWcLw8n3CQnfpgD8YQ/Kv0oEcvL7iLIM4GZ8xjknziSmjbd70oQ4mQDTil2x7tBCVBoE5NrzP5LwbJij62ERpNDcF@CfyECCgAQj7tux1l600V4rELD6yBzohiJZeUXw4PuvZNnxzzbXcqW7fJ6oQypmbbVjYjbE0IlIMkNJq0MvkejIpuYDgVBFrhvAYYOtTSvEa9QDvWDnJrN5355VxoEi9j/RLcVfIsj@d/ynPfsOf25l8LNO7YvLzYJyTh3U2foJu6Cm3uCbv4VdJMH6qYyKoiMvt1x8sWnyQX64j/xCfIFB8hF6Vb/cQ6N/3LPcz/4mPUvfMfCP/4xnLkEPHEqR5Lv3C2md7@8Azv/Xzk18nHHRT50iuLXRyfmH50Qt0R@zOGJeCpOu49R8jg44gZ7NDX55h9X7u4Wd7RNyWSSa01stPWv5ZrcNB9csiV2Ij9sE/3EDvqJbeW/su3wi@s65yxAUN35244/otahwxETFc1/1E54//axD2xxD@/Wv5sov8w3vG0ft7Q7Y5Q9A0MajjlR3Mkt0sRt3r1jE9vA@UkXvseXyF/sMPePt4h972FjnNyMLuYOaTPjKae2v3Oj4JzU/s2Vnrj4j98ZOHlvpqDW8JlEAZevTmyIF3pUUuK6m22/qW3rQQsGxlK6RCxsxBdlTaSwbfB2PZob8OxBcrqPJlAGxthFKCe7RvbFoszEQJs5E@KvwP//5bSVT4L8gMevD1n9Ex6y@vWpkV@fGvn1qZH7To3ElnND18k1DSsHopnJlBuQ/ukFp7tH7OXT7TN29nSP7b/Y@Q778ugFe7n9/AzfMXr84snhwQ6D797z0z3mvxGVPp/rDm65Z9D1u3pLJ@t8IZ9fZYR55q0Lq@xU67Ondku/BuLZdLX@4x73ZC3dq/NUe9e6M7b5ctAAN7N44tQE2Yr4WpO0OOGJ6yZQch/XEeVdnlhGus3Tla8chMFG73jwD3DztT2SQWgfFy0r@Yc2AN6GUECj8SVZ2juNS@sktLSzTDSc//noFgSh8Nkp236@i9cX7x6cHRw9P2X7RyfgPf4Sr9lhuwd4bcyTFxhFgM@Odg/2D3a2KYAXIJ9laFujA@v3FSGL4NQqravOsHWVHZioFQrfxGs9YpGIZctTES6LD63g@p42kBSuu/PLTtHgBIS9sn3y6eco1ehvWDSKN/dig/BXqsgTCCt5PDQCuYlXA1QJhkRLReUMqT9mKxhdpfe7JsidYRJ5ktaJDZ1Fd9CMiAvS/DWwJLBJ1JDRMuBGVPIi2Bp7DQJyIh7PbBLKOuRG1gOZGxpWO9KDSR@Li1lRj4zJW1pdQoo3zh5YLX43uAwAuue7uilbz@EAaBASARwAbTAY4GlX@gEaSVhJQAw9VPwhYI0HvO4P9m9QasQDriLgCUpCdBFEqBepSzXWdDTD4v04cayJcwfNbRkGJXEJHi/JMU1pcqUtcSD/izU2XJUFyChwwQ6MbKlUBMtuQA3A23tax3NZopZEazCoILpl8J1aXVMDdY/swg4eWLrGbQSUbRlfq10TL3wKBE66XViqMM0xmyyHn25XTPz6Q9NByiczOeK@Pao0bpjSuLT7wQI8@X/ae7LlNpLknoWvaDU1QrcANAiQlEiCTVEHZ0cOSZQpyjsRFAaDo0G2BKJhdEMCRGHC69thhyPWO571jvcIH7vrsF9tx643wn7w@8w/7BfsH4zzqKqubnSDnCP2yXgggaqszKyqrKzMOrIWGPgqaABRRdcXGFZoFPHjpogm6AtRtsIAJBJcPuMjHR7EuTfpeokCwtexXvhv3tiikctxEe2ID3GnTti9mJyNcCPkNcagojAX4MTQSclT3I3iPrSSNYj3hs/wMMQYGfzQ3U1Q050HSVGcxBFE0Z7Podpp02W4C6mSxPPZYKW@RipmFG1/h3wtj7ZJOugmK28uxHjOeIgBIzuNMcxL38CDRbOIOEHLa7tQiHXHR0ZYPf5g0929f/d55aMPy81q9YTVQrvHmxd8KJG3Wcglh@Ghzk7SaUA50gTSQjjpYGl5npG1JY5yiQwMl1MfjO@9VkPl8bLqYjo@a5dOp8S3b10uVaH7JiRCk/DUirVb2TiWJMtUpmnYAkGsO4FZjKwrU8qEU@nrPXysA3uhAS0yRD1Cx2u02vL5Gi3aNW7ogWYpCDuNu1vht@UDC0Ki6GPp/VH9wLrrlnbtqoSiwaSa05Iquiwx12xRK3qohOarBXT3l6MD/X15dJtLuePp4Uthu78U25firVLKx8XTkobr8mg/WoKWJ7evhBbqXs5HzJPkIjYl6Uo4y9dWpMxfQPHDhb6jsQdocO4dBaMYqUZtMhxghDiLF8WBNSpg62hig@jp0f39w0PDpIc5t6Es6D18IrIn1CDiviojHfE9ZFJ2jjKa5Cc2nmSKeIonSXbZYM5svBxVIWyQsmgPpSzid8P7/lTcjuCZhUwIvHjNClG2XJK7c6mDwmOBeH6MJ6GMuNO0ChYyq7nCkw8H2SclE7dbmW3j8KU/UsaMNxXBumipejzTEUlDGKeD9gnufGf337fZPt6WdNjA8n5/QhXGQ/hdjJdvPAXCI9wpdpI9uKRbZJfSmRWS0hXZdnQtL2lhf32BUg9MzIUtrKl1YRwL1tg@vibNHFrWxGkA9/lnIrN7JtY7pYqnlB29Q@140rOSUxAYmeAGG3u6VEDx5lxMYdQaap50lUGuj7VrxM2x5LKJZ4wE7kY@0DtgwW/cTKuHNCnQtktJVb4ZUjxLJCjJNs@sjMwEzDc3NtYuwp2uhSxe@bq4eQ5J68/obPSqraEMZyEdFQLJffC4LPNjAVjSdC54gT1LDphUQTB1MuaURN1pMtL5A174PWtg5uDZURnXi9JUbWOa4i0bO89IOnYCWaiDNoRVRXnULLT@fDk5VMgX0rv65enxYEMgXA@ff8EP1R4GI1SV@Oh4i6Oigku@HeKpuAhL8FPtKtIvR9gjTHthxO7rcZN/8w433pFmintR8BLP9builBOOBqCUTNyGcs7ao/O3uMD1lpZMOQ/vBIiyftnYe8FnVFY5pRfQIQIKaiAYIC6TaaDmX7XU/ULI28bjgwV@5RMBtA1MVzVg8XrRAL9nG1cVyjKtxGlgn6ikCifJ97FV@g1Ox3sJ/mgwU@lVTu95r3wMky1SdwSW1@2RStsVkBNoBzzzpTJMAUxrtX5/1qJmV9m3ORvMGJX0jmAGfMtBoFKvciqeqZJJx6LsJE5qchJ4UippRUDhxORHuiyFnveyRZ1s8LQACItlY@gPmo44P3XbEr6jLa5wRNyRUN4b9grUKShiMSo5JexhaFkhQsd7ftOhA5RCAaFPFncsD6Q9Py6gA0M66Nea/EVCxcWIAfwrmBCs6sKLlI/3XqCEj72wO/EM9Xp8QiopMMgKvg9lHLxrHB482U@iRo5baKNQKXlgD0XwWDBG1ZFDtgwdHkyi0xYnyp/p3Nce50oU/FsBDYOxBsQ/07mSAKFo4rA0zt/23hrHMHmPVKdYPbspOl3WWNXB6QaTYXT@dvqWuncKlp4DInDbmDu4SHB7oVnESBQWthQH2otrn3kttCtbMqxCTIVSiMpUxOYIxI3r1Ji35wX5qq/Un9B1MDJJSSutiFEiUBMEaPJsj3HBIPSgObqnCmRMe9kuvvKZYgwnJcdZSC4Zt2xbFPekSlokdkkipTwiWzERljCFxwkhxYqp2UYvMN76b@Pn0@WkglP/ZtrbUa2NsZtFN2pTDA27BMxqU8vmXQmtzr1C8tvCgBM9GN8HL8R4xICA3tO0ucsyngAj@V4AU8pBgvEAWoCjUZAA5GGyAEjlFzG2srmMh15GkWyO4/G4yE4OlRhdRpFsKjHTya6Ix3qqN7oBWGf8IAl@aYEjqM2vmT0HYrNAOG@wGumCQhTJnWkxTYv/2Rk0pJpmCJDHpvxaazbF67p6saXwyRbRORCV1xoEdRCFU8FpTU@vpdP1KcnY1YqnITSmUsCAMzVTXdwXHEkkkfQab2rxsKJLW/w5RltLTI2gcpoaKIlQDmglCcqjJoYFUAQhKw5nFg2UR2IStJQNqgk/wetYU7xqo1GBlrJBtfGxgLWShTUJWkqDLug1UpTJtlcG7Q1reefZOXasjk4j5U297iTimUYGrYAxFMHw0A0tAd3zT/zothEbWvTNAX5QaNc3RURsmQYO/sYtZfpQAWlq6ywIsjFC1BaaLeVnEOblKN18iw1zZTwm4PF1BprfdNBjgtC7weAITIIRaWQIh0bOYtIU05uGS00jo0GXkQzTWDmHn3O0fo9XztndcWjf0Syb9txkthoJLQp1ksnCP9rZkW3hREHLNzI/DcE84QhGRhKHEyct@SRwTCKViksc5UHQ5cXOMuJqSGftGNKb4tHNNA7cTVmsiywIaJoX84EbKos4RvQS8LJK6TikU7WI48alcUiHbRFH5fJ8kD@VVZd3Lo2DHcEsHNVL40AJXGxTc@UcEMz5r5klaon2wGtRIrVd7iRFQ@FsJ3510nWRrqqB9wUJQwJ@mvqVxYcwzHVZH2hu0KXaA52OxfawfB5JuzAVk@Ze5QXmGpa0F8YLO7eUyiuw2shrGNfCqAcTgdMfqPGdMfhTLnpqkUQgpHUPdGKc7ukYXCTsTUd4H9IAIZzAf6uFR7NaLVoZenJ48K3DO49aj@88QidqhXUULt/gaRk6rrPq1E3I4tWWFp0pcg08aoHVKJAe1vKIP4Fmn2YRejkWS62ca3Bzkw0opOTSepEz9F4b70KWQzuDaZwI6ai1Gegei3hQSt2svDLtGFKfwWSthL@2C5wQDMuJ4IRgtOSC5mxx@edDPqHyfPg8YsCOccx3MsOmzu9zvLikFTSMyqvn0e954w6eJamooKXci3gEH303Ck6FRy7ECnqMQevAL6pV464Miivur7UHXQx5O@lT4Nszf9A@6/Tazuh0VOiHrghPYxX7IQa5LOBhqgdH@4dPW0/wna79e3RzAj8Nyjt68Gj/4NkR5jyFrDWRvH94eHDYogPqh8@eHGHE0FSSqQMKLDGYSEgAPT54785DDYZ/m4JJvhASgr8J/0Qon7Lhj1pT@jujax5lPgrRokd46JoKFqW0shH5Z14wkY@3YfwJOcGX8eYJbsoALfmqMQWksXD5U@TFsU7nGhTxMZ6MIgKlE/BWqiXsZAmGOQtPsADFIgrBbqfT9A6vKGMeXuQLRlaqLF6QwWIFcb@rH9LowGHydDbsWhKdCORZPveGAIm7TcVJ1K9sFuc2RpUc0aGhdOFiFWaOKgVHLWaXFC0oTqUXtEeM9GXXRkFeeAcoulFCnRDfTKECvIPYMEol3z4v6A9EiSzQqvx@1Lmh3aFPwoj3a65ofcRhTfmcL9BHAVHfxA0cJSP884m@KUUCJvan6DLHMd48V21G/2VleYXZUr1jhfz4vLzX7eDpkXvA8J3I4kAvFLMvljux3SUYaGFGuseTeYBe7I2JChNBlvEwakBDReOZwTcIw0g1F9S8iX@nIrRrFw/QWCBwtg5rmpzL4SjxklAYMQC5eeauuR2HseFrCergMEPs6BC1LIgPdIh6FsQrHWItC@KzjxnE71ulkuy8XaO@scGnmRP9mVH831XxSkXC7sij0HFhwKcXl7MxI9lnHAK65OJ1UH3OBuQ6ZzeXcpZE/dl/AG4dlyhVISLM@BK2l2D@/A/NbV6hu0Qr/R3XUFNQaJyILS@@wozrhfeEiEuWxF3SNLZfLMFmmrIXs8v@IJaID3KE5rNfJmCyxeYT2e@Gaj@5w3UlLluLbzWkEfznIgL3yyBocXk5vijaKF/gxez6tsIiaxAjYJA1HaSeBski@XYpyVUdXy2TZE0HWb0Myc9@JWiK@SsD4scKgnStaMxM0P9ODDQ6mg@FskBDhsQ7NU/iXd9c8JMkD3qxLPAnMXYq0lzO9@ffSfMdl8yE/6NM4aQCunzJbs9s@H@6LI61XBwfMopKJbfdigxRKuVCfPbTmA9u3vQwWzZIPv@Ti0uv5pf@g7h0PM3vyombrQaJLK0C1fGgZCYVPVbYuP@gAVRKBjfaNKrGnDbkcC4WF8aSFaipbHHjLJldl9mzzOw1lZ1CPmcDS1pJGF@PDKMdfmGQTKP4O93yZYNLZu66utVmc4V0a5eNdXHBHNpG2TjiKo5m9OymHI4bCSdjEbXItYWxNy@QFdzIdH7C9rh9OmzjA61hMHTECyB@UN0/C174OFGNqxjmwnkR5nlDX8e0JgTkx7novt7BAxXAqggqwme/2W9HwHa3OzmbDHAPzRV@FQZGqlYxZBw5gsPJWShw4ox7d@IPoAYuWmqxiQhu3gi4pFkYTOlLkU@RziK7SLJa5XPjDoWhoyTirTv2RxERcxd9AQz5RAYqkPB3NFhpwuMF9XNCxKFoXVGfh/7QszR4fMXVL2sJFBeh5HKpBklGuk00HGU8AfJ4cpbAcC56nM7GuJzjhHjjx1ot17HlPJQbY@zhCyHqdoQfGnURg45CyyAScYNonMRSL6/b3EqE6AmI51kSYr1cX0VCI8yiEEUUGVqdLG/3KWwRXWolHIRNQVMvgEUYoxftursKtYMMxZdr/uYnH/@DaZ9XqzKN3tTxh23wGehFkhgr/jwKnsjfGnr0T8RdxRTuf4xxM@qe1/XP2vhCTaShBuHKwQwdiJjPQdAwaFUwAH0TnFhaLBhJEAWrWr1z/75x9N7hwbfxNhQvIpAUpIqjEGwbZombnUom8sXBYAQRkrAI80gQRiDJxCKUqhWCqRpTeJ2@pZ3Agtb67p9Ra9FafoAn3XlcphBitslBfXCdEM/W6mhVR0gJxn747p8y5mDEp2ezEQcjUwgmfB15IPxyKdJaqBdDZNP79Q//ksiJGyVg8@G6yplOOs/op9xjsSBLMlupNXNrlSBDjZCL@MIm@t7PCFnIj3RLRVi4omtFhSS72j/@W4Nw4OYD9J5W0kjgKV2I6BNGpHYPqOVy8VUuxPd9xtfzaRdAR9SZJav4COZJZ4yXhiwtuXpB8/36h4JjgPcj3DNZQuNGgt1CZmf8m96zVFZ0R17/avhze/hHOlJxzTUPI09UmXg@/lU8TPVqcuhklu8r2uhMsZZZ4Y//K0v66Iw5jB6MAM5o9a7KHCs5PP/13yj808KV6QUC85uffPrTuI7T3JpNc@vzaTyapou1mObxfiWlkt7HKcMsTXO74pdJMomRO3W1n3kIfpHX7tNkY0/zhjyIvhr00wuGfR6STyQSNeCnFw75PFzfl7gyB3u6WjnDfZo7zCX2nIGewn8jh00YjP@qD8bpsp7PHfP5YvH3hBwNPrw8utAt1aqwcFbJtN0xavQfI/Pi/900N7r2w6W22HBxwaICdOg1JWQPoaY7@sg/T78pP2e7Jk6tiWALskYalZqgAq5JexBmkHLdb4xWHZsO3L0MKrtfjUhhXq0OPb50Pxn10Oug/bsz8jzGtP2Hjwdka8bvUF@CtQ3uCt@2ofAEx8Ryk3ZwwgXxQXQUc0i6GhgBugfuBv3fUdWt1DiF/I0raSyDgE2iK7Scjq5QriMiPIlSrZnpVLCfmjkQfq40EHtXHfausLFEHSmObJxzofL@3k@VRlKtFCSxp1CWLsb5z6Ib6IgR7ZVTxA5h0@WjdhO/lCOVTJVTQO7U/S@6tkiRy7clNbA8zD/4czXReSGeZe1BffDKK0X8x8cxsWFyZ0BNf/JXQmDZN2KVkUv5L2THh6yh8ojjTHYJOjlkfvbHJop2diNxduNiJ0tgzPWxjAePjWdP9w@Ng2dHT54d4YKMHhhR@eD5jh673ayXyYFNLhIs@LINcPPr7M5qeSxeftkv1W2q/l99itVntCXXXDW1Zlpa7keJcjVZbkkbUVdcuoVE@yyU50UL4I5pi9q67qZoIXCgHwwjHK@hB18EGC9McMBnMbex@POVad3rFoQZzyW6/puslrYYk7@YgFMddoBbM7D/3NX/l4zfjmTQktUMd@/crN08xg@1kCE/CfS3LUGJlc1G4YsvVozRLDoNhvXCiqHWXw1af8WYQbzK@SLkNdxw6I9GXkRPERgn3hAXoPFxNj9AqwIDdGDse/j@0qM7wNsSucHLpa0XYQsRtQQiZzQzzGt7ZqHgn42CcWS8Gfgd@R3fEb25Ln@FsxBDPYSel/UY9dF49iA6GKLtUMWohlHA3/V3qTHcUghNDhB@4IwnwyqFhPCGPVy6pqOC7ZfA2imQg6r1WgDWwmpZNu4ehx6GkDKfT/t9ky5Ye4PeUw8bFy08Q0U7f4CX@Uxg/tTEE2YrxuMg8rb5SrS8Z6wiaVCLe0ZRLJhVBvzmIq3qF7XXOPBUGr43RbsnJh5cEmvqFJ7HdGiRGEqZNi2xW3hOqx8EUQwvj1uIArx5kyiBdcSHdFh4Me5vXCN8xsvD05@CiZJhiATiI/4piMYJRIi4AY1Tbo9x4Kh7NWAEzsT6f20bQ3ChPQvm@rY8f@zjWeba5jbGz6aaYINiN4nl29om5kz4wXV8FYbvj@v1KLmCEwDkDqHHimAc4AvVQecFHfRAgxo8bJQ/R@ahCdHBsCUDisOONqZ6Wvx1x@dw7T0/JAAsWT15449EE5UTotqZnIQOjwWKfu6H4cTbuLW5TgzR2wMStBd0E6D1KmDG8G9VYu40OhuoWmxFp@JNbYrRciYf3aZIWTAoSc4wFkIbz@WBAN60SXSgKRM1hVawtsqcdn//3Yd3jvbvl41KbQPB@RKJgrW0xuXsEuXTIUshRliEh6/TubnOQm6F5eJetWgL1vf0Zi/pDEsEYG6NUdeOrKJLxYT1zIhBrfVQV5XVm0jq/RU8T4XDDVmZjDGysCkbV478lRUTRRppraAIJuw6KGMX1NUT@AWKZwEoV1dACwjt1kKXB8P9k@SaO1crFTWmtulbBRRrpbLLd8HMezBXvjSKh5NhQtsWaey0jSIoOYxow6rtapH0gmM2jFO3@E5YbHRhPlcGwitrYp/LZ3iGfeTC4oY7Cu7OZP9ZE7mzBA1iH9eati0Siv/7P0W7MY@P7g2syD7HKe6NK8O2OazU9znKlVVkjw2KvXEicDTvkXKN3KihCnSC3syhZ8N6907BsbDe6DRGln1OJ5C6rrtmnwPJ8QjPio5AGXpHgNFuYFo/kQY/oI3Bxqg@fz7E0HU3cJ/u/UcP34MuP8QYEGF0/EHzxrVquVgEb4J2CV2Mxm3cP3j0BGf7se3QrP8uTNeiXcZtRcTBxXe83UPcl02sWhVHIWjOEy8StQ/vzo7aJ4/BHLOKbWiCpJHV1nfm8ClaPG@nt5FrJjsXbKQTl6BOx16/wZvO89B9ZZ3YjQj@neokNoCEW68T9ggKuXjJL9Xq/hBm6/eOHj10izttA7G6GaOiWOoo4QBBIYGxMIn88ITo4JN3KFUR360ggYFPqWjuJuuyU23vFhvzeS4/D4N2j6NyFGMB7lmTspC4sbvYpY1xLAWzkediAk9t39o/MstQdjzxbEykdwhmpLQ4YKArabC4oaagKXD2FGFcd/36dUrDIpPQdeurqzZu4cwBG93TBLQ8sMaN@bjt9izVkO2R75B7602ZFhkndadebQ/D1944rNZu1lc3bt0Oxujb97ywez0EFeK28dk3P5pdx8t2tOV7Egz61/v@ABeVrq7f2Dzw7/7u@1tPb963up3fqZll80VI7/CORzoD4/ZrsUMPOnbcZekiJoaAs9uujtovg@p6b7W7ubpZu9Xzbm14m6trm90Nb22rs7W11e2vb3Z6W7fatza6nSqGdqQizhlt8Jss/ki2fzmyeYbZZn11q9@v1W7e6m1s9bfqq2tr653Njd7q@np/s9ZeW7vZq292tjrLrbaYnwIoWKl3ce5Ia@B38o27woJuF6Xt/wM';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
#xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLcons=>al{} 47le.Vu 8>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Niecza is an old Perl 6 implementation targeting [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) (.NET/Mono).
Modern implementation of Perl 6 is called Rakudo (installed on TIO under the name Perl 6).

Rakudo/Niecza Perl 6 code:

```perl6
try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237
```

It uses the fact that Niecza doesn't support [`｢｣` quotes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Literal_strings:_Q). 
See also [exceptions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/exceptions#try_blocks).
Spaces after `try`/`EVAL`/`say` are mandatory.

Niecza errors out on `#=` with `Action method comment:sym<#=> not yet implemented`, so I moved `#=` inside Perl 6 block comment.

Fixed polyglot for 05AB1E legacy as [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/174891#comment421460_174891) by Kevin Cruijssen.
Added `8` before `v` on the first line. It is multiple of 4 to not break Cubically, 4 breaks l33t, so 8. Another way to fix Cubically is to
swap the number and `D`, but it breaks x86.
Polyglot also works in modern 05AB1E now, but this may change. Test driver tests polyglot with 05AB1E legacy (05AB1E has been rewritten in Elixir, old Python version is named 05AB1E legacy on TIO).

Answer (score 7):

## 271. [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 000, 12530 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers95 6 4>8370::$/\0Vngt=Bk:pext se>ExPrs min94 Cr ~-<u Uithw;re-  hardoc 8  2:t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`[[[[?"271"]]]]@ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8 \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
#\* * * * *|!o51     ~nJ     ; ;#p'34'   \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPkB3ua97CaHZN@@94JodAEoENUEqtBVBRJoNm/MjDdmNZbCK49nFaPRWnckW15p7QjLDnslh6VwhPTqUPhJP6Dllw3FhuYfzJ5zMqtQAAGSPRpFLEigsjJPnsw8efLkya@TDcPr/OIXMfywI6c7Ou86PvNNz2ct17o0XY1tj9gTw/Jy2WVJQqgt93zQM23fK0gxpjNmm1ds325aLfBjvnNh2tY704WwLGN91zl3jR7zO4YPLxbEYrtm933vvc@aTq9n2C0PIJcZOzIgsD1oXjCj4fmu0fQtx4agFcZe2F2j12gZDCBMt@@aPqHPMUDRvKA4kyGrjD1zXM/E5Jum5znoucbYhtnr@6MyvOQBwnAt52Dr@adTkdcZ@9SAnPW75nAqL3qGvbRMtzUVQ9fZF6d7e9O@Wfa56ths73b@9GX2wvWMrjGNf4VtDXxn35/2z7Gtc9M2WFZb17LTgats2zVuRVljrmm02lbX1Cy7yVTWMbt902Xow9qOC1Xmm918Jp@pb41jak2Mmx8HTqEtBR9muOceBDqXJjhNqIm@ZbZY23V6zLC9K0hJX8@M4RHt@iQ7NCGDwGjsjQexWybzbKvfN30eCMU1XQqGlFnXsi8kzn1HrtMaNC37HOBMoGt/4FOZPKkJ0cqsL3hYQweLERU4GGThxOmZ0brwgHkh117fbFptq8mJYw590/agvJ7GLKi7K6vbZS2zCxHG2Jsp5jls4EW8Gl2jozU1CYmLqbDeRZdZrNnvMx4ExYAs7WXyzOw5byz2DsK7HY8N@z3mWT0I9ptOu22a7J3Z70B01mtJLUdi8Gn2p0oWvi2aAGObULqdo6@Abj6S025D1lqsEYGDfFCeqcSG7QD5XGYbPc4Nzf6ISg9owhhtx9HQv@WYnh332ZXjXrCG2TSw2JiYZ563jUEXUrTaWB3AB5bHeg48oRJtBtmCyD7SAnFjYtLMgmAyQfWafWiYWL0OsgvUdVDLV64B/OF6oh59qwfcYflxj5mGZ6HEgiieabeIM/qhLHOgtNFKZ5cWNDwgxcAl3J7pEusTXoalAJRGyKvKlWv5wBFYii12ZBouO3VNM8H51PSaRh@5NJokJOZgCj4WRCPG3NiIVw734sCgPIZm9IEh3eXT73wmGUwrscV6Eb4lWS5Klee77HrxDN1cZgIT913FSLDSN8xLn52Z8B3qjfS5eyMBVgmo0mVpp@@nDbUPGVR9yGDaQCe61Mus1u9GEmYbU3UQaTYcqgW1AUKAfZGikjUHrovSfUxU4wIK3XXsc6AnFNYd2LzKVzNQBcB/LS/FzEsTeYDXkXNFFD7tAIfAP4BGJAvvcIig0OVAUxQUDdL1nO6A4CCm52N7BKpAVMS432ZfsLZhdTEKhCMqnmvX9IA5Mc7AbmHN9yzbbGksyAZJHRfa4iUkZwBS8oDW0IvIFsoUAENFOFRUDPrwm7/TOj8HPFvNpuO2BLt@AczepK7RoMxC58aQYR3b6FK2AC6FqfPokMCl0bVaJOUMeySSoExQqlfOoNti1FCvLGhyHQOErQkCoumbnMmdgQ95TLGeccElosU5FwreMxpQsZQApU3FVtmTHailJjRz4hm1N/Dbeab2KyzupV8pmwVlc@HMhMwltMTSYjp9XgSG05bIC97id3HOF1sTXYXnG55jtaT@yO84dpapTSY3S07ftJX4BI54Ku424gkNJbWSKFqlpta27JYS3wBeLEPC8USxWWpWrUKtOBU9miSguUI02FxNpZmQUdRQo7hM90C50ECSfaEKVyTM8epIcgzWIt5ImGm/S@4RI9UF@dJBBgE5pHld0@wrGU1PoJhAuJnlxoBZJZ3CIQpcsGrJeCyejBadMEBJJwqKjfXUclBsdfsd1DeAKLbXB5nrIu82DeAeDzs1H1S6FGsQX1NPCJKFZOKVGQep3QBBGvARNUne5DC@ioJSYBg3ocmWbLYiDRmEALRl37sljbsOageUJ@x5QHTYmKhxDlUDkXlBtnhBeErkM1mkCxsECmJrmCyvNixoBNjcQKYLno@UDcCXsxwGsPFGEpE9PWOEvRpXDcYNBvs0g/VAPLgj1jRR5oDwMXmHgokMqP15oPcyp80yajaXm2xjt5qY76a31K9BSL9L39mSsPDRxoSChrVBze4a9vnAOAd54dgQxWg2zb4vBBWUxPNBFE33N@Spis5T8zrS4pPptKkTCdSjcRoo5Hntia7QQOki1HYVdDJU/fhYgLUsF8QS9ORTqQPA5VTi8msEmcjAa3lOFgINAJjMHJrNgQ9SDRj4qmM1O8CzmDuby0XeCU0nD17R1EGyq@0wacyMXn6clbR06IXZmItCxRq9jQc6V0RVnvCgyo963I3Z8HozEDthFqEjiPhqaUMD3rsHZ8@xnRlIgZAhWgSZDOH1AJrYCSrF0HEFahc11lBTDqsI6gykBrR84L@O7/e9AvQTlt8ZNDTglPSpO9r3D21klrTvjizf4e5G12mAWPagfaaDFNLNQcMaThWI/MI6fONJl6CAtT1Wgp777QC4Tom3PRCY5L@DwJEgmQQ3oeC/MgASkAaEUtoeieI9EConI7upyBNMKaeYjG1XToADI4ak@QyVt8lsvgGv6VwiWDQzWhqh0p7bJIca0UkRPYJTtqRHE0V7YB6lR7IMP22j65nwtAfdLr4ObC7lFK4rJNi19OgRiDaFkrN6/a7VtPw6D2WPHwudgi3AGA/VpjbqTAmI80gMpjUQKAAjuh8OrfnOCSm7SgIK8uhmImHTdR2Xp@t3XOeKkQeCSVGi7jg9lO7sJSlcqEHDsNaycXgv@lLqSo2ZKkTYp5K@HI9rbxzLVq7jCwsL8UK8DD3mwsImuDbQtYmuJLg2yaWSC@E0dFGMFLkwtEox0K8Wv6kGmIeJGjaHIfb276y@YlQLheVayqjq4pnFZwLoDD0GQKv4ADzxRKmEzkRCLl9BQbVGe7L0O9jrnTRdqy@I8JlxafB3QYVlIgNUnOPiwKCIysvdNOmVXNAuYDDQ7Chu/KyaOaudXZ@1kmc38RTGThSNUgMKBekpPe3cdQaghiSqKwVVryUS1WVQPhqleCa@pCh5FYZxMBJJfJJPJA1ObSVuQm@onJ3FgaiCPtVmxyV8w1Q2kQhJBflAhQd0bSWuXech/UailkjGIW4inoKhWykeB8o0kQgeFRrb0gSBDo8/54TZSSYlat4wKsXvre4U/HDQOxn9aPDuHcoujqMRclh3YHAtry8A0vt2AKth4NSgNQhqtBnK0Yk0PnXafFS0gz@Vgz3JHFJtfXq4VzkuUTIdw7sAnUI9R9g06MpAFbelgTToDlqmNAsGxAa4muOc4NwBJn7ebDLVYQSmNnkmIt1Fk83BBrKGFE@Hqd3eZBG8DuR3Z6IMhIT8KeZd@kszyBIHn5mnMMk9kNg7JwcTU2S9C9AnWNProvKturwA8Jpe4p4teoRjjALbpzGaDQom8Bbol61wLsB2bBVlYTCcc6IJ8QkRgCA/1LZQk7AmYBBx2xrCkDiG8ylC9UeNFbX/HceGwampvSRpKDMQ5DhbZWoz9f8jrkhpTW/cOkHTB2e/azRB3k@iO5PZGSAECZROzw5JFG8hnh4c0Dj@vjKCKtU0bKRfy6Jx6sDyOkheGEtgL@C2gao4SMXJHaLaPmuClnsOlDaHls9HrdDCTzDKU8NTEjhO2uLjDOQy1JExU8HMHSmwThNG@CboyhjKp0tYxb60XMdGImsVQA2iqIh1MIV8FnmBjba29rO78@k7CzlQ7Ja3HqFtFOs0cZsetC7b6TrnDlsCAGRNTeOMvW/jDCeMcnyjDy3KekcE2jp3YKg/yYOmGc6Zri6H400DIdMEr72BXoDNLvQYYE6ZT/a/roAaoucyGch/8JahT1jICJbpMqJnk40BxCpAF/kGa/Jrs98ZuRPs5Dli3sSnyUNqmHwmywAVEnIlWvg7ihpt5NwH2nkQ1Apcs8peoTEBTt5Fx9UTpZ/QVnizgRLGprzRNyDFBNJbFT6uXxRcZ@kJuRVOFajtnuMb6S80ENH4I6GGrFpM9tLxhXhaVfFXpiCWLbN0y7xMo5QaYx5WzOZM3EPTbKYxFDs3FjhmkicInEOaM/jY9APF5M@ABmHM6fKfJ5Mo2Cl3Ydo809DJn3YGpmQ2Ow6Tz2CIES2ZDB1EB8bKKlAeFEAcl4TRxIqQ5DsDGNa1zK7Vs/x9mrPv2jh20Uh4ayi1ROgOyJsxgiPLBIWcTziMOxmcVx/3UfY5hz8GSU5YYYivcZK6Ziu9NMb2zHFcGFd6TKc5hWxI@p4ISDtev6X5Q0DAY1Wof/eCfv754W6lfrR1@rSUHnhuums1QEa0zHoPBrNdaA5zPpg3nCGsAO9YttOzoEQByncX3WPH8bnygAsHD/vEMGKA42C3frC/fbx1/JXIHPXoVm/QNTCPhcUpgBDHCcHciabpNBzQLezBXEygXBxuHx4EWD57cbC/Vd@tHB2eRtC8GXQtQx@m@xfn8wr0GYIwXctw0h92W5MrOjRMnZhFEMIGx1xFBmNTpqrwq6IfTxRHZRoGoIqM3aOq4iywgfPcLsvqmfX1VsPI583VVnNlZa1ttFutlayez7XzuWwuAz9rq@sme0/gqmoOaeYGXHxWBCeQMA3IPD10bSXQcGAo2gSNZTQzX2HoHZlr5nLm2sq6sd5cX183smutZSObXzPN1bX2SiZjruqZdiOv55fvzFwkG6hajd96NAMErQ4nCygQhJ8Cj4nmwDMPut4Va2Wz2dVmrr2@nG3lMiutxnoml2819DWjsW5m2ivLelZvNbN6IYiLM6ogJTpQYahV2qCaBkGqDoEJKehMo1VMq4zBMrQQOIvLKGL6wTIyDhxEwAoGDMQiMk7NCv8c@gdLyDhFI/xX0b@HC8hjTZZeQ08BmCdAXEfW3EbguY6e4QryxNoqiEohP2eFz48kMF/rmRtEfoVr0JHyXes6@V/67faEd5a8L1Tsyrpj72Xy5ivQk2u/orC3gmYCh/hWCB9fuZ6J71bQTOAQX47jwxXv2eimQmaBhshWCRmukM/ENRUwAzDEtEaYoqvq47A8hc1bUhdpzQyeGynEvU64@Wp5/Q1fraiLxXLkZt5ATkETO3BAfz6wcN6@PdFipHAEfibJwTTC5ETSOCQ7XiZh6uXs9R05iogLA8u@cGjgHLrqGU3PIZYQRe@ieztmG4Ya9DMBeitTt0N4/9VrtOlnBgB2utMzcxRA056i64eu1kgf0wMnQGflYHIqdyL5htkewCgo3bBsdN8Dpq7nCbLdaFjzQIESuPkgeM4AK7DjAYxEs9qKpgfDXlw6AZnN52FP9w8JsGHQIG5y/p9NEN8fuD7EEs//9t0WVMLtKuoYIxoLho66bV4Rf7Tn1piIii/0M7t2x70@EYZc96FsGrjkanRDx2zUVPuq2jHcHg65RHUDg@IPcMIdvMZzzudigufsRAqMiDy5zsBsq8eaM6AJdmpJhCdGg@yuY7SIDHwobJkUycXK5tVgDvmgMKLwQM8zL6EZKxdsvFXA7wz8Af/F3QH3VaPVx@9dTVRAZnJGQzdBRTYalnlHpbvGxaDlqKDpUZExY6szYMelp8k6td01Lrizjs7ZxecFdK3zc9AnxHMe2FUHxjY0KE1f0eM@vvDsgddXG1BZPjQceqOm0LsjBbfLf@eBWGL/XOiYTzWrSz8PqPSQuYhdQKUjQuOWJjVCNGuKzF2jMcKheufjuQwTJAUHZE6pmUxmlrHbC9d@o1uR5sfHvpLir6/Pjs03U3GSzBpepfkmKpVPIFOZxbaqeyoWOi6rZ3TVbCvinCvRg6njsWsGKM3bqM2u4QFr@aI6zEuoPvq5i92xZ2rCsMsdu@5g9nF2gi0A81aThdgSrbrpdC0Pm3Z3ngSdXoAbp4nb2egnMiVtzSJsi3Qmr6OGrtlywWn6uJQ7h9EeIOX4KiquU0c4R3PmEa3pXOF3rmrRcS5N/ju7o3s3M1cPkFhql1jCas7sUVrN@zgVtwPRz2w6XszMl9/szvSfbAPBFEd0gPZAvvasruOxE/q9iyznLkTjv7M5OkpBy7BVWg@KumdHE5nqM03Mss6pV6N77nRX8@dpA37mVv7AbWOfIJ4PlX6h9NL1@6VXoB85ti6ec8X@Rdq9uK/uaGnCxUX7iPOOHniWCBOLkvMLCCMJ3Ikzu3B7mTzF1NJ8vDyvAtxm58oYBc9fomeZR92gZ@mPSN8G9Q8jrOfB4btcB/9lUlu5O7XWw8TTLbRr9xUiUrkXXRM6Mvq9VaUsm9E/MoaeyTxcWLW7A3NgzpRVh403Ju5vv2MU8vBMZUQxFsVsJ84I4VxnCPVOjB8flGvsw/HtTgFjdC1o5PdqOjPlXR909D4OuY/AcYSO2xHP7UF/onInRnH28d2U6/SDlu20JjKJIR8rkfL361MTirxn0vfOwRUfDOLaVmklk8kI/SYyfz3xctegazmM@8bivxMJk8845TEszoa4EefsNMZTqVD11oWn4qTmw6RTdt6MAAGvr6dtyzb9Ef7Oq5JZ0rbhON2PqUIQui0L9TfQSnHh576qvKUbid1gbDz34eHMSaM9b9aDd0hidArUw4H3XdwQnXp9UDWruGQNrfR86vXueaDIRO59qUA3T5NLfOtEd77iKWZUdC2vrd3ZIrk66zTMrsEfw9WVu/Cta8t34gtVFqEn09oWrofxFbDximpsSm71R0AsqwWDnI7ZM@n1jtGB0Xoz8ILHXKChg98ZwRqtN86L17dAUNj4O7HaFlGlfMeGYZlvuOcmjmu6uCoufOcJ52BWfSZx93vGucnPVd0lPcdTHbh1mI8Gx87Zkx4FvuusCdH41o@7WQEa04U58oLnTITPRk2oz0Hv/qm6qXbfpI1K9zV0LT1zMeEeXdHuOB27Y3b4TqDwbV7zAI70@Ym4uwoB@T/vNBnJp@gupShlu063@xDKonzk0tJx2jPzVMFzWi2I@lF4R0YDAsTj3ilA6OuJQNTpz2s3HXMAXZbn@E7fVOltHmgXJ4v47zwpGizu/LKzUHfOEABFgucvi//esem54fj9Pj3q/e7Aox@KqtLxullVuUfJPIQrLJ9vO@J8a547jWbHui9LDdPwbesiHcwI8dc7R7b9CBUspu6it9a1gHjuSENuKEXDT/CxP69KxeQS77ZCx@w6LrCdgeuOkBK@4zCv61yN5cPk/olwGpevPqBjXg7EyuCMYNIGcGddsIPsjiUQsZA4l8FICUeFWzUzoLDoc2eUJrZ3RlrH8jL/macXTZWfMhVZv/2YKVGx7YEmB63IzC34T/DPxGL0zM7K7gzOvdvijk/Yt0DFwp@ZNb11jmeapyqaVyr0QIYtHvPone2mcfs2POtQcwPzztWV3J3LKwSnd1XDseBRhwfU4WDutFnX6nv8l6nt7EyF4fYS8m2o0exhs6ifltnmayHouk/T6zkuHiIClUJtuqbXxKl0lMhcf@LSx3bOQTKrXTYGDmBnFuH2qvXM6g97PPXL5@a5gdsrDyzcadmdwRWAdXrx@j6k3xkYnvWdgeObM/FNL2Dfh@6ZcW41n05QPkAWUFTsweOPCbZHr9vEv@pYHp3fCBx3zDkhk3G2RT6rg74/a7Q2NV0fHoy@e1oloiiJvd9M3WfBHvHQgQsGGG7MTGvWTLzTp3HjiFx3TcJbPs3MiudMrpq9CeCu5K8Gvf7AE4/ZqdM@negUde@C/L0rC8Si@hakMesYXX/2NHZkZhZ0LtFJjp3ztPCvra5zzr7OZxioaNBpo1I@g@G2obs@MnxoEfYMBqa0H7hQipMeqssL9hZ4wlxmqmVb/t0TPL5vwBgpeGJheGeDpxDTB/irPflYDOrpbIoc3KnBQN8@anbxUPzHjgS42AUuPKFD6@gMz81H@V4kY@4IhEHvYptX0fHanYs@BexSHXvgq7jL/64@ZfXOPqXAhvnVCGsw5TuVZy8SUQ6h7a/36aEmDAQHXnc0ds3deDDFeJYNytp8WTwJHYwmdk0yaXBMGzXvibPVx9NTJPJ3nVkjnqMR9D4PHjJBBzLo7ZpNXHm8N@3nzjNQ3aAr64PQ7R2buGVgSpbMjojRDpym0QX6tO5N5oTQzugrxoNro282oH67Y9dsXWwW4l3DN@boTjRxSCPA0HUvr1jdhum@oRnBiHveoHYyQ0/NIQ1D5jMMb4Wq32xyhRun5SbayPTajtd3HJv/khDOwEN/drewge6Bfh6@4q7h/uWJ3m/mIG2ytIeXfLuJ2eIH9@YV1zUbTpf/YhHmiAPb4psLDNcyvfSBZQ@G5MdU0N1mD3P4Nt6MtobTHF4HGtuVBWPscHcvblbjW4W9qZEUqMSXhkdL/rPHNBM7iR@@q6hjuE0H186E4yNXziJHwu6R4@FWab41oQGVMgSBZjQHgV2Be7La7TV69DN3TBKp6WOzgUfuGnR@1DeGs5TIyaNjwnPq8FYg0rDhrzLlCEY9ifs7sukh2yTFrT79kEC/mskmQXLPLbP5zkjcI0vDVkRzyWmDRrQzG9LkJjhQc7qm6ndwj2Xa9@cJjOfWxaD1gLWuYAFl0DNxzXpy5WYuUzlehzjCmb1KHwpc1xRbt3GXIDT9wI1SV92ay7KIHv4Ptz9LQ8dcX13BE/yDoXoO4uz@fQGQ@YFri8dD2O7I8fy2NTzsoxknx50nX7BYOYgCD94c0LU0rxBQn/agy@c7ziM7unotGt@BNth2wNUlEe6bqmlfqmTiaBgsV7pGYEdmbh1Obw7V79kdeuWF64EQoPY9eqb73tH@weGp1vf0O2YOccPfwOri6h5lJfCDApJr/hT1Ce1Ve@BihQoPXI2beMzELVZF@x2jYfpG2pg72MFQ05@t@T09fXaQHJ9cZspOx3V6ZiIavHNykoK8s89OZgZHY@8Bi7ed4dzo@xVdT8zgwRc2rQnOk3szUpqH6dSEIStw1FN@iPZeranp9M3W6ahvfgFdIspe74HJr84t5HPj0jrHpsTW5xKKWhtb11ZXApAvYDiOh6LuHpd8boEmCxp6k56Je6CPSRtY/qUX/afVE5bhmxHE@SwyJRUaHfFS4uQg@FmusE7gaYFdNHHMknrN4MAPeBrN5gAn@IBcGiNARTGSyURCErGeOlesh0aXMJJHp4UvrH6RZQInFq0DihHBo70EhS0abKOEx4FYIlHkpkegFYFoGJhF1rYC1FueZ53bkIUgB2Q1Ci3KcINUHoPRlx/grVbZ4vWwkCnoN6zE5ILMajWeY/xQIpVhn0w@HfPo1UWjVlqMq2p8MX5mF1gmHoKbXc@cDW5MwEJm8SEyHNKXm4NzyJZbSM0it5gD2gBao@oYdgs4RbQsKL/L7b5wo0KnuIv8L/@wJYx0kTG6nuUZXSAI2tmDRt5xrjZ5ugG5@n0DjXwhjqsOrhBg6urOFvOucLaf2@aC6nqxd5oXFn@EUT94OeJzwGEuOOfgQjSeXvY5Y/DchCdRRcJhrKBQMCwe9GzQQ1t@x9PYiUUHkwfu@KiRMHVo@y6uNrVSbJ@1TNywS@fNaXG16zgXdAYNc/KXf8jtHNGpc3EaOEie7JtFUsTD5ToZF2o2nQHkOkDyznQdAaIgkY2mP8CtDGRej/wTeBabDDABt6uB@SFKhtsg2tk6YWqFxdFwH5oLKVptZXHr@NMvqpla6RvWS5v/7bvpxLUgnPyJur7qySkWgBRvkLGiwTkIHofGmbw4lHmC4ZF8SwidK14faHSQMxmeyg94zHH6QbPBkRRZTAu5UVgiUdBN9RzYIeqR9TliWPOK7BDR2U8bu3ayfuhBA4PXBKHmra60qAz46rp64rMcJIi2nAxwcXt1dEgdbepglMUhe8@o@wVZpecy8MYJ2UUzTr3SdnCcYzl6zCa9azYGtNX8MqtlcyUqzmK9tFEmF6hqDppTq746G2Yz6tlwrVKDwaEg6tnZ8JNM9kuguuNCrMdpbHmV57vXi1o58/69Z4yYLN/Ei/xYEIiJxeuj/aPKyenW6YsTqIWbQLTt8cOBgaxBLqLzvh2nS4bqgC44SvsI@RO@jcUgIyEoRU9mEqigtazKi9wZEU0Tse@JPiu@Z0bCbwMImda2mBT2DMAFBjEbUg0LP@ijuT0m4gqTYcRlFvYf2IBCwuDhqxmylEglsxIQSwViPZBUbH5hN7nfQyh2L5a7ybY5EwQpFqZXDcN5EWeS4OZXUu6@4Xl//3JzLHeXm2DuKDeAhr5BnL2t/YMXx5XJaEEnT1K3tJ4TR5K5cMaWxkd6gY00sgQiIuLuhJLMZIrAX0Vnxi21mv6VCcUSwrHZ45GJQyn/sjRmTKBMCY0F14QWoiiUA9RvUBGZPjENw7BIFoM@OoLumhcxFAJ7cog6yLgmC8wxMnqr4ScoBmIV5Aqa3hEJcSGv415U/UkFLQ6Lhn30wONtbk5XFfY6HoP/SK8UuLI1NmSiO9NrTGVZ@HZN@xwKHMAmiryPYoucEPIiz7sc5heNlUKeWm8MWhCkk0DipDH00l2j7wXKYIw9d3yzwN4OHLJmEgiTUL8gO7kGty1MVcst5pKVFBiJgL4c9FuEb3/vpITaGVfNSL5HeW5gY0cFQNzMr7A34LtoDpsfBOf2NjnJHWHaMegqaVLNE6bcQi3BY5eWZ8GwhCqhjTpOFyQllkYUHE1Fkx0bttX1QCdpQfcNGoqPXS0oJxodT@VnVFWbyTHgSS1UGVNMlhDWK9029Qdd6RWOk17zyIsER5i9CM74xoKqAuXOLTuwC11AQ9E0n1RgvjvA3afl@K0oQRYK5FI7fq8bAZxh9PTMTH/4zd/hhk7PfHD/ULiHmW14@3Xx1gb3bwQhug5v/yx8y8Lbj/jbqzRW2W3rjuN8hoY65h7oBeZ8It8qGAqGwEI2FSiscqzuL/aPmNdEw8tYoT0Y7Y7rCsVMME5hVg8445IqGsF5CuN6HONRqjh0BOYCJkEdB9UaSs90awoa@iuk05hxXCfUaBuwOeRbc8ju39sB2rsFTSy9mltd0dOQSfUyQEimiM7xVCJHmEgUQDBKl1a/9LrRZBsbG0z2mkbXLK0WOYOkF41Xy/LrMKOLACvx0UKVQRyIMo4BYWURTVk0knoCo2JvFtfjKNhaDuc3UAkVcgBIAr3twHgJ6JyOIBUws20OfVKbRsEoCKS27UQMXQeIVEDEcaNV1uk2OT5piJPbkVaqRatBfolgNLtTkGdxbPUVO/PP7JqwzsuA@342g39tcP@TGSZ7OWehcabbtmKVaUuvWBr25MR2cI1gD3LLlGw6u5zWVxMRDpUFKsgvtvf3gBJaOEiMpmm9cfre1k5l/7PDo5NbNsMIMj4NFmfx8kbyTNVS1VroiIf5niTq9l765Nn2XkDKaK7Gs/QIMd52PZ3NWalN53RO6i/5oc7baVPArYT0zEMR0xSfukfHF25jH4emI4A7/EzZrVSVxPVNtbZRPrNjt5J/P8sOdExbQuYC15lHVqDj09nELIZ3PpzinQ@eFlgs0NFcAZ5j9Z2LsfED4REJ4OABFpAAkpYOoOYJT8jAIZ8BGlvpyfJLJzwSfXyWiKzzhjmKQJ4G11Ng0xoblRTWFDuG1@laDQk68BZaGOW2kAJjP6EVJc3rdy1fSUg0BVJCNQiEmCIuqRgWhhptLlDIFjThSrG7DDQG@BISNALAFz8aeB125PQjc1u7ZuA6Bm2E7Q74yrPJPhv0AK5Nj2MTRawJ@okKkYFQ8TCrfFQNLUvYZxwm0QYmpFdFK42i4FqvlVOGCa1jDlvWOQhwJZGClv6JDmpVaEECC002G@04yDhO4U/xLF@UpB9lpnM4Rm5UDc2yW@ZQQbtThRrop@gfv3p5GU/It3iAbIXuBNYFp4yGBg3R8EWLGBvcnGps6@HNFFNWXdfX0XYXGsOAaoEUT3z3AJzQPyntntFnyoCs2XpMY/SqnCl2yvPdBFPL3CCOzZJJGlXDgwJAa0bQNrmIcZiC85BKugS1g76e3cLHO6vPqrqm1cBNiSTYIs6o7UBXjnNRCQlGSRClQGhLWLesgDni3KtxzoM4GC6ReT2GJl1nBJMRVpq@dpAWVGpWfhwxSzZugZyq6@sFURuTomadAVvclvJaGtDOECGBlgr0FbYNgGp4SQHeZoFLWyAWnnxu2rYJBAKe6RnQBxsDYDI3kQpupUmNjdpTCjGexafCWAJkdNLYfSV@3cX9D4vpIk3OFG@gT319hp1qW3Sro/T/nNbSxWtlsVsapUHRSZSVxU5JTy4vJZOL9pKyaGNX//gxzuncLIImUddgiDQEIHWxmygCP4PmUVq0i4vGhrLYKmWXKAa8wiDtGiJ846W160XjJr34GHrqFPi4vPEqix7ZS81omn4D@cMWsphOAc9co3lJupIGk1@0kknMg7ZYxwx8kz47SZLMPjtJ0/RRUWij6fOeaG5TUjWsiVsX8nACCm9R0SDYsyjYxRmVegA8NnW/PCtsju7BE/4cVwQY7Tw2vaj6L0@GPFywCHkXJ1N23DotN1gLBBwqQER8TRmJBAiTX/wipq8yWVncXF3uXibjuUwRfvTiGsuxTxbPsisxFntiGD4M2dNL12e7@fNLZrazq29VtWq1tbe1o4ujoy@Ho8SZEo/tHL6S9RUAXWPr9H3oZ41l53zYx31isaW0FEsv6Y/X0unXr1@DyoufalkrByBaLVFV47WqsiY8euW1taXUan4pdfwkXoe8QHETSjabOGGWlWZnVt9rteDrdOiCKCXGP2xzE9MDB/wz4dcbtsk53DLPzwcVY8T9rdgAH3u@iPvs65cvX6LjJX3Yu2MRP8YxCnSxQt3IxSiT2Uz2L/904SZ1fVTf@Mvv9dLmAj4O8fHDm2foPtFznywsfLK9vbKSAsJx99HXR19tbW2t7KZyR9Xc5oqaWdj4iz9fWMhmN7LphZrn6bV49eJLOZtZkbW//P14/ejoO56HdYefZaaDE3/z8NVZLscu2Dv4XLQZ/pP7XSviNtDdaL/DDhKU5RIJm3g8txw/eRXH@nkX03U9NqK/OhVtgenlzbX//uPDtzE/Vs6mX7rw9GNvY6v5GHeCA96Wg7fLWDm2gWCrN7FRulQqgXPtv/87iF/@DPBgyGgDfsq5ANfqKFZWSxTlfay8Cg49m4V0/5/vfleKlYeQiXJ5f49ly9klwSZ6/rH@mFy23wEF4yym51cOn9CrZT45zOayG@i2TbxYpwPDURQyup49Y6LydFGFWFwdf7kH64Ab69SJsQB0XOcs4Cj2Mkb8AQxCPMLdwoPYhnu8nIZ7eWYYS2vJlewTu/gy8pl4@dV/jvH@stWFJ6930@mNMvTz@CkUnpzVRSNLs7W87DhPcOqvyA6EbxF/ho6qOgAO3zPyVPEjyBfLl1J1TqKgjQUhbPzGol4xQUkWNqdfAq6Cn7/6j3/1k7/6Mf39hL7/RYoFu5PU6mWtHHyAf@SyK1@fiVf7GXvGP7YN//ANXtEHPcBli5nJWPgpl/GH/sUbueg55SdCyuELQYyjzIVjgbyidKXYN@k0wxbALoPCPFkoLOQLq4Vsuh4Uj4rBc06OZ5HSjcsnyrMJnwX4o3/4hK/4u0A@wptAbn8WWPkhn5kdgBSrxqq1Gm/T5WgF3f051pDpNPFWj3Ypl1JMBSmVTB4DkzLB2/A5S97zeQFfTauLt7Q2xhqTYr/yT1lisWv41JLqzU1Ve5UsFsU/aHfF8A0/3AVZq92o6sarcjJZpSxWyyKv8RUnvuo82VBZrcwLQL9a/dUGoE9uVDdKzg59NeIRtfaqXN2YxAGfDbVWfvIkiaR9AgjKizUG4wqojZuNm/JNdePmZmMD/jfo90Y8wfdm49Y/PcafOTDj8BrW/1k1XT5Li0ZZrsG7li6jj5Y@A0cZngBXrUqxa@QcVq2Rzb@SWtVXczWVUQNZAuGVLuhL2eV0bvjJaiULMsBD8Kwsp5fQ8R77StB21qUYjhvW@fBhnTxef/j2/8Lv2Ydv/w28QtbwckUKbbzFv4N3@PfWx7/TJv4dv8U/dvoO/459/HvWwL8jD/9O3@LfVgP/Tnv4J8VKjIEGt7iZ6WYuM/qFfgEOi2VAge5kOnoLOh@WMVlmlBmxTM/RW@Ay4S8DLivTZplzlrEztq5DIDh8lvHR1YbHOfy1AYsLf1Ymg8gzlwxS6WKXRuaz6fm@zhJnUpXFX5ugdmm6ltFWrXott9p/W43XirH02Vma66Isu1Ikc@k3N4zV65Xnu/V6GtvD2TPncPx/eNiLvt753zt0nh06PQf@Dw8Pn52BSCsnnyTVJ/AplZMb4rEZKxc3zwoq8nLA1bH0xuZZeVlF92oSGDWLfsmP/IwxwrO8cCbBWP3ly6si9bvFq8viVZEc4St31AWAAOMOiFUU/TX4QLyzl2nqY6/gc0l46Q2dVxAYuLgj/fLqDDVKGD@E/0CO6Ouv4N/6/9f/sxdMqdYS0AiubzYU@iTwL5G4vrm@Eb/lhKKIF2UD/tAD3jHK9U0ZnQR0Da6qkqglbm64H/wqiQ2OsIxpbJQp8hgQhEcsTJPS5T/Kr/aJafPPWRwUJxhZK2JZ8OxsmMkkig3wCdcGjPe0wpQo0t6bxQauCsJoUk8QRG6lWNSXuDu7ki0WV8TLWr5YzAv3oqKs3/6UM5v6KmgHKyuJRLGYEbAwbiwGTkBhekaziI28GEtgZnnLVzI4O0kXpcTlgvz4sSKu1tns9xOPH@vrmffvQ696vWW59Tr6L79/L9dl3KZTWs/Beyb//j0InXjCcZXnDl8gVlSdfZItUwrrjgulWoNgpqez4zQ7hmf4vqu8s/opGbfHenKCjJtnMo57Fv/5j773vbN4CTdukO@KjggwFZbb2FhdKZdXV8C9moeCy4t8J5BynlzXEzeLaZkXl8mL8ZgI0vNrCfK9iWM4i22wzTI0VA8/7PomRvXHVnIJpTEyE9fgE/jp6@vck62sKvnkuvgrLSRYeYmJv2q1upxcWVpbelIDjef2B4Vq8dooxdPp@E3p2ijgLNZNsSku0cCDa8bjx8vrQMx8pngm1eu7W6dbdbx/E9fooUNk6EkSWsL1174br9KUY269VsWC1c7i8ULxCVW7ns@xWLwo4NQ4SHuWX6fyxzxPstp4gnVIWKe@S7E@09eWoaeFjlbq03aptQxr4Yqzy5x2ewE8oe5YAzcHeGa3G1w8cuW43daV1TIXpNjRwdZO5TSVBaUllt3b2kllT15sx3R8zY3fMZjFltHjuLK1e/gCYhwdVLZOKp/uf1F5cQT@nvTmnWGahjkwzav6YHD1Fi@nMOtmH3zHn7rZtDzjzRujTx8Yt3Dh/OFnP/jws//lw@/96MPv/eDD7/3k59/@5Afw/UP4/og/f/Rv13P4@/Nv/9kffPjd3wPP/wLf/wzfP/35t7/9Xf6l9z@D73@N@P2Z@Ebg@FcCXL/@829//Ps///Y3fgrffyG@P739/c0/nf39yffnfzHej//gbpgf/Tv4/hHHFcD@6He5Hz5vwf8uh/uNn374rf/A//9C/KHz9z781p/hj3j5pz/9i//64Xv/KZvN/8W//vCDH334/o8/fP97H77/ww/f/8fZD7/9r/VM9OcPPvzkj//Hn/zR//iT/43@/5B@/@gh/x9@@k//@t//9f/9138ivn8K3/8Arj/96/8EnPq3f/wz/P/xH//tf/4Z/v@f//Jv//h//9tf/1fk@B3u@H//xb/lv3/zvR/8zff/@d9879s5vz@48/fbB/h/@w/g8/B8PgTPQ8r1sT7f/lL5@ftQY5wK8ABdAsKyoMNuj0yav/hkWJA@YbHyEn5AJFfz2XxyCdTPpfV1kMs18t9AECZBO/3JP/nw278G7P9bgAze/ld4g3/@AkE/pBf25ZcTgSxJcyJq8ssvMVCMIr@MQv0QPN6nQRnPPHkPEF9SMP@wEAzS/T8IDOCYAAvgJjNAMLjlk/v//Nt//vsUEMZF71@bQJkJvKPQiwj@PijqD7Hdj0sThf4hio4PP/vuh9//xx9@9jsffvbr2DWoK@uprRT07HdP@gJg7gFwCLj6EDgA1HEUCaP@BSkLjoUNnKiU9OTr15D7BXDBiGtJyi3Dm6SXya2jGyIm4Y2QDIdJ/IV/aWWd4Qv4DMkXniwJQdtJvBw@KQ1LEEageKs8Q2c5D15DnG0oAV6MxOOk6nkYy7DhNmGBmKXkMasvlYY8YhI9yoQB2UZCr2NZz8rJfGkXEiwNdxniQuRJ6TU8X5fK@dKwjOi@oSwAjuQ2JAlQeGl9clj@Bt5LhBPgpeHuN5CVfCmZLOfBp4SFTFJqqTqlqeeocFT2JKNyoz9juPVy8wk0GVnPy3w2BEjJBDT@JsfQCAjgEH6WXBLFof/ASd8ljA/1NCT6cD8evoneFF8AAF5VxR178FVVzM0TCB5yVElKFh5JjgEolyQlKkAJHqSvJKUk1W@SXiB9yMPHfTZQVCA6LM7i4iK4Nsryslw/hCEkjNXci4LnGy6uKJIeWWDy6rqM3rj9iW/sXDyisebS7hL86vBfWaDNzFSW4pK0GMeJjDjPWpJ9kuTfJ0@W2CdQdnqO/SSmJpedFSfGi7mRTMpZSLLswNsSFTFJiHCigf6T0quYxGJU99BYUvwXHlqJ/CNNiTxelaTk@B2nH0UMTUtpqZR4avQkD004NAoVT22RFEbGhz20bs301RWWkBS6fi2BNdQ0SRmTnnnn284QhhwpWU7pq7gWlRAzN6eFLLZWqVLIwO9XTqFQ@kZfWZPgSe8DvAZOXEgGfNMxXVPb2MD6L1@rNL2ETlBZV6VyWSzDM10qn1ROAfz0kOnZjMZguHK9spZdya3kssurq7m1rL6yur6ymssvg2RdzeSyWX19ZWU9v752E1LrCQinVGGpkdso/6Nbn//pH836zPbFj1T@kg01mlG/kcrdEt8OuohL8vJZRi7SXBfRcrGaSeFfdnkZfiGfKT23VltY6F6rWOwz2oN4jZseIKvStYod3yP4MOmRxB6BF3wgDVyUZGIbyf5hUWwZwNtc@bYBWc8BI0M9nAEnc3RQo9fX15GvFFv4@muflcsw7FD396QYtMEOCxbJVauldTS6hLU1cE0KPWdsd/@L/ZP9w@fa7v4JjAO@YtnljCbFbm5u2uHSDr2a7PDwUELhB@O7ZR3j3zTZYDCg0Aa83wwNqR/9FPtTHymbVbPL6rKu6sv4f48ji/8Ph8/CfxZ/IdZyVuKnOLt4qieYPVvHhi5tcLskZbxD0DFapfCqWaYkrlulltOk0zrFdqla0zyokWJLazitkeb5Ixj8tSyv3zVGpXij6zQv4kGghZcP4Ym60kLaTWu4Y1lpJzazq2uFBdxNRz5MaTPwy6Hfq8CTwHLrhZYWJP0M6hdiZgvZ1dzNhrA7VoaMYwbKmNy1yEXBhkH8DW5TLRhtKO91k2/vKMjZXF6@edIzW5bBzjJ4Bup6JtjqqnwTwEFCOE7EIbzSw1s/cLNzIXOWScyJm4G4kD/KlrQhLJyUaXW@Ck20hpchVmsbge2TsvTNN98MaUNMYd/2xc6Y7Eoe/ZmEcukxdPiPde7MrY6dGXSeop2a51AjIFhsdoAb3H2HnTp8I/W22ZwDsdMx6G7IHdeB8fQvD7Nt2Bc8aNfiBjPCoKcGWsz2epbfmQPxot/Do46m@w@GodJrQAaRgTjANvy4XceZBbDGXhzNKeWz0L4VbqIhA1cAfrz/6dPTyPO0srXzVFpl24fPd6ceOQGUYweVvdPwdY2HBlFzIYqvKgcH06/iAb1WkSZQFlhuDTfRBi/QC8UM35BTdblaK0JL9W9AucsXW/ZgU3/8WN9YXT06AHKu59gqWynnl9cyhcJi@izzBZSstH1R6OOuXM8sV4ZHLp4ytNdXoLjsG3VjwF5AHVwVXRNUHeAKaJUsz1i24C9Kz3DP7rrOD6BZnkTnQPHWQbxh1JfQkkbLubLpbF2jOzDZoM/mesIDvdDpWucd6JSvnABAahgGg@/HfiB@dKoFiHWnh8/TIL9bId0Z4LhJxGqzjKSRSM2u53P59eVsPpVfz6/k9NVcLqVnU/pafm0dusOMntdX87l1PZVfWV9egT4bQnPra1IMujGrnU6DYqTLMjwLgNZu4kU5G3jjkKN1ylKMT2iyd4qRgNoO3wdMNiGOjFc2gkzFYwlLVknOruCZoWWdAUaDNVlsb28ns7cny9v4gustOxlZbuFLLp/JrG3LskkhO6BXZGXZ4XHyeJxY9vlLJrO9I8sDjgDNbslyB18qqzhqk2ULX3a29vYwnTf4ksX4AHbBQ/hLN3hZAzAbX5aXadgny29DdAC3xRNaoZxW8AXTxJA9HrIDYbL8aZCfTAYwHHM4juFpUNatLVne5y9bWxjyGRU8x7P6Ob5s0UeWXXgBJpTlc3CcYxcgyw1wIivKchNczZEBfngpEZpisqHdySNOICSRLA8J2mheyDA4Ef6YzNOnT42O3zLP@Wfk8mcTsgYh1nBQ2Wt8@mnj/LzhjrYqnx5jyGefPTXejAZu47whojXq8HEgDoRc9EbTH8jjfr1udGeGfA4h9lRIfVQ3MW914y3kSXzOMZFe/TMI@QxCZkwKDzk2@PQAtIGf7R48t40GhQQfCqHnsNGQi8io/qhv4iQutpkLG2RBqmc0XaeI78PSAosr8dSoupqpFcmf9RSWuM4UbzC8rdDFt6jYgwJ4PaoOS5kaDFrXsuJskyKfDbM5S04t9Db19VxhwdjUsyvJYQHtqjvtOIur@qaiP156pzwHTWN5pSCfbW6qclWvbWb1fGF17dXSQJYTBfzdXF4rvAPdPw4KPv4kqmu1zbVcJMraWtJIZwtruAksUbwBivjQDTUGvlmvK8qVaVwkEphj7NxBoaLishEV1Sq2lWFqWOIZY6NEcVjSi9woCMvcwtVCq1QDvGOSYzwHdMPNTAEn0hVZX8/LkH46rSQSKJVQjsDz9ctgnS98RBwTTv7RWEHlF9Tq@dWEhidl6k67Tpf0sddRyPEiufQSD7fRwfZgDyoNPL2CdIqDHuwOSJ2yGngzNlk3gOE/t6fG@EyYvrYuSWWh8x/xS8KK4vXTpzsaDAPEG1q50vZQS3VcDS/y9idCuAWmwOsU@jXtqYk7S5uB3w4/cq5VhjDGQ1U3CDgQx500YZhCO31avFbrOB3/ndOL09Ov1Zso2hMY//CM4NGcIlluwEPuaBPMajGjVAaXASNthXIJJEhcETnq5XKpXuqZvb4/gjIH8T7nlnvHiPY9XpjwyBBFv8ZjdCKgXsrcjOGfD3psmwPRWbsgWr20DfTNFG20qGni6yIbxoZSuYUGw7ZL29eDAmqgN0WzZLqu48oxPKC4aZcGtme0zSPTxbNx@4eLrM1MPIXW7Lw@qyDkDmrSN2rZZfZEPhRDLTcSk16RVySd8p2QIte0uxvXi25gnKG8ShTfwpu7yJSWtp3YXCm2lG1WT4BP5nX7dZtl2epKke6PUBATiAOiHFLESJTKnwNijveiUICMCJa4AJyY0CLUiNWiECPRt26K56UqQr/Hnw1VlmuqWn1fk8pFqQzSpTiKGSVv0OA3vWYaMChfLQ7BT19bKXZYo9R4NSy6pT4MI1mxC9Uuhsd8y7qB25eBSIDn3Xvlw699N7Gh5krcr0i43ndBkahr9dJwXEHLpWoWBs/Z1RUcTK8uw1eHQXUWN2Smspn1VFYHfQL0DIgP3zV4X4EvwIC6kdVxyK10FRgiy6nMMKPpKd3UU0rmtdV6nUhdKKD8EcESKd@p2MA14IHMAyxLr/A0EsnsUldpOczYUIl/QdoVqZBGqsP6VqqDaI5No8vBEypbXlK6iwrCLJ4O@pVqrVCoDPvfwSBFfbu5mlzLJN8lEkVlgSVKnvmWKIyCkUjQXwBuFtMIzBv0qpkFKDS0P/UGatpf1NeyhepgsarqULrM@/MNuSzXoKpumAR/0cVI0LeK4BfIQK6hjXWssV8ftemuCdWqr2eLAkTqC4msyMqZHJyuUOLxtWw8nogXcfJsAfyFRCfxG4fuIP5Y35RBx5ML8noWwseC/FYO@Ah8VZdiNxIOXRmMxWPX0s31zUZ0N9rnbDQykmrw@pix8@SixNK0S0Srx9gCuVStTFOcW6Wt8@OtooDe2pFiBdowOd7Txs7E8Ximphc@dm9KcqP8ij/PcGsWJCuRJbsqq9FSs2nhwIl9gaeFNlkcymW4vWo2u1yrZtegLwcZHIBms1B071ri9OabmdIbyTJLn0myTNKHr3znczjXZkI5volRe2c718EEReEZjpeZYhR4@67WEt88t7rX@WWVj7kVFvuGJdMa7cerp7@JQf94Q7UQ7L38/HU2B/ViO4EHjK59EO3QneZyMiSdfo0LMZtydk2XcQ3mCeufrL9ae5V/9ezF4YvDPfYkU8gX8uzsSSqlx/X4BnsCGr11XJFiZ@Hy@vsFJ8dXCr6xPxPbVYuxfnx5BXcyn5Viw9JKsLVB0ctlVd/Isk3gYlYAyd/WV9XM@zJnyTIFrGYh5MOv/XRluJGH9yxozgWgaS6ZLZf1pWwi1v/w7b/BA5bXlS@2DlgczV383Z//fnbt7/78X9I6evymiH7Z5bUYQKJTX12LXV/3r69v4MPDcrFajOdpZS0Bbr7HQ4@V08JbX9MTMU/lb5DdXMx7L@zfKNlMHsJ2DvmbvArUjK3HpFj@2ev3jG3AOLrcOj@3suRKp28tnCwWYOgJ/zgC3QDHwutSeTENDICzvusYIZjYWyqXy0u4IsPi5SQeFs7maGGoelOsAVHxg2O1JZv@TG8J//D9FfdY8jx4D4LhFSflN0yWK0OdLaXT6Q@/9tvZ7Orf/flvniXe19/XvwYRvL6@vqpnY7@AfNxxgi8YoNG8Dp7FQ0c4sGNz7qrUmrIUwwtM24zDB8M8HNjh@XVu/QffpEvUM4jEdaCjAVq1QmBLeA4pRfo1HVpOFCUpVEJJf3bPmynCwZbQMDC0HelaeoRB0HuxEkgt6dEYFXj00GxQs@51B26ftEGF4um1FHsMUSCFR2hoYoHOTwnRp@pFll66HZVnmducIX2D9UzPQ1tTIJmlRxDlALiUbhhifQPP4CGkZYOo1RCE8kkBrSqkXYO0uzxCnXwVKj0HSDGeOx7JBgVbeoQHikgBh06ZWRsAUGQJ6REQAMqgCMRWjW2w5QS7tpLJ4tg01Q3ugkO7BEZwwkfCaIithcfagshFhLO4@YmBiyaZmKjhphn1DJBwHHy9pgRDA4xOb6jU0CG@B6MCXHSYW6GiscePx7kqlaxWglGJED9a5kJzWmM7QrcSAGTBuOqTVkFOMTuZxMp@NMl2QPEkZRe4TiXHGKiNR63w9UaS4P/BTIscOVVVFFDEAoj64q2iCSSDyEh2XodNtC2mZ9cSLMx8E/LepEyRiZJwsHg2/EQjS0FNnsUb6RexwLKmhDeBR0Y1gm@nj3gxkEsDvGsJz69zYSAOb/FbOFA47ftB7DAWFMXqEnTbcmF8QGtPgbETZVlPYLR26EP5oN1v2RWGG9NyCXxQLIRGkxgGmpcQ6SzQzDXZ5fL6jk32KOhsL27fIythnsStb/BsD@wrgyxL8VRot1skR9xcF3I@WZOyucksj8fFda6GC4PdgDYpZp5rZHglu84UbgIOpxjtEF2CIlGGYVRoII0bXbMHWToxTYY2EbxCOn0OSsWgQUYQnlnAV509C7oN20uLW53SV9aFlT5Fo4Cq0wZFVRy6i6EeYoX2iISlATIn1rUuTD5YVSZOTXosu5oCRTAFlB1/gbAFnHfFk5EZCE5xKPiuwWONO/OpSNwFZZS4/VzWF5Q61uh7btnHxZubLg07Ql/6vJfEENMbecGRaDqjB@9aKHKhZfJzUXE8GBUe2JPE2e0SnSvWcEK8r4A6FZzkQycon@YlQKi6hH0MCM1mcMQQWzGU9hF1ANT2oGWhzRDfLeDZ2xJa01Ka0PSEgLfZJ2w5K5FtNTqNLg6PAw6s@tIkdgiDqFgOz29BxWh8ngHkCrTOXgvCYmhCh7Mfxg@4G91kP2fM3mxBoMNOh9IqMd4sgpdc5AVbB7eGBkVfgMBVyOGMnCwochLQJuWEzFGH8aejc26XSJYU2G1MKYYYBKkBC6oK24bHzToKgx9XV1ca2ZwZuJZmemi91cMb6dL9cwu0USftm72@uHjDwluTxI1wY5fKrTfjBYabQ7o3cP3xiD8lqY2nYN8OLNdU4m0vjn3gJcjK/nmPDvTjUXuP@GbPImvGTYWWQz3BZtla6jpgswKymZqP3yASxhDNMDVKNVOALNVoXqTaV62iCLikdgfIobLMwBPNwbnBS88LXFa/HUI4Pm2kDd4b3Yum03VQ9ZD5XOo4aV7CAHIUvIr3vjWESLZ5xbZc1xgpFJ5AaORTZUTaDRtB704h4ITehF1zq0nWsDqqTUQfhtGh7woXR108zi9d342UG6vC8CEPH0L4kIcPx4kGyVaHNa55odcNFgeZG63zBJCIZhTA3HBbW@MQwgx6MdM5CoQcTfjdwLdZotgBvfkb1GMpYAzgCTJxp6BtvepZzfbMq6VaMn0OPC0TIaDGAXW1RjS9aoVupH73stt3vAkvG43XQOcj8o1ezY7gBs4rWMawgogxOL0stHFy3tP4jArv90WBAQOqWxCIGsCWr1iJYmhdlAKBcarymMY8Y1WRmRopWSJI@IFWxEnPCRtFVIsgQv@wSJBNCGFByxG2uYUQeOniNaYBrEqXR5CZ1HgtDpScaipcpBSpkiK5UtUgm0B21EpL00UJwqEqqlNBkWLeiPqPZn/ho7PfhnYxO/fEsLxfKErRpmIO0SSkKZoLUZWVS5F6hRykl4yu6UIHVeFqqOiUIZmldDCa4OlgEbgpUyVS@c0Erx86oyDbciFkhVGpBEUclXiz5O0iICkneBjNE9FGASOI@FyAAI7MzGimiDaMRhuWSlxwsOGcaFeRTA4pk0MehUMP52SyJqLBICk0lonVU0MbaaBQyYBP570l2gOVmWdcotFX9gZtmsDgKUhzLHOICwQPoSaNfNaszUy9Gsl0RGhNIUBGvIWgxa8CKUjTAk9Xw7dQRnFSBjKKvwk24LICGIxEcJHbrVJCJqOhLuj1cpL6AWi7crIqyTpuR6K/DP/KqcAz@Oq3PTOTkPqkZyY19fcP4llDykYaaETJ0DMrKJBxwLJFZjxALblymDJDeQb/dHDXa7rRdRrpnoF7J/BS6PAG2EQwHiBDfU/6jm/4zspKgQ@CLOKvFwKcRczw8zGAdW47MNSI2sWzuB0/O47mCpvOuW15ZgrvnOUquEkL/tzOtRTVe4XT8SRJzPrxYSmi5gyEqmu9jvcV1euKZ3bbiUJodBJfNeTDeFzC8Sy4IvFBDgmkh33FwQu3/cT9ONFopIh2ajUvlMO@CIxDIlsMhFUT9HkI7YCqwjxnPBIka26oGjd8hWyBd5yecw7qHVpqxNhT6PfHuDFDRr9PeUkxA4eohYhpTWoOSjNlJETUzz86Kvs8qxiJMH52EsEEMVLMnaYxUtadkVx9bnI8WpDeycfn9ySa35O780uj6uk886F2iQd@XNLLyhgDAI6zsXx/NlLCMPKt7ExkJfRGBYpHeHAWW7Q3qYU53QLQLQGutYE/UuGbR@ZaRMa/mEf/uyswiF55aPUZeH3byQjkTQ@3wClk594LFgMVAN9PoOy5nVzI2rsPTAtg0UD/HuoKoK@S4LLRFhA0zD4Moz05XAwRiO/hedyJdIvvaXtSiQfOyJN7mWIX2flVtFtvmV1jZLYUAZmK4A1KfAwjM5JXDys4CjoSeg4f1CnQSSWihoSR6ByoMIdljNRlxIz0LRgOYoXcQzPflMP9@fTD8FuiGafsSnz2GRT@eDxGFsfJQHx/1B9xG4pdfreIkKO8/@E1iSc17ycI0EHsY0iNk03cJT6PlbBID@gRQlhtsshkLSnotpxe/3YdfhyJ7i8pVG4kUimo5Qkrz/Nq3LqrxiNcEfAkX895GEvex3QP5rkIq3FkYxG283FdyC3MuH@h2VSiGLnPnTXm2LdkAvrRvJs9p1epzxCoYUySdL5F42rSLxISDoH34YkTSF/AExGem36dM1RQNpyjEveGMArpGf2I1iJ8QBsHLBEqBrb8KRsRKClwA/j1TZhmc26azVtpNifSDFvAZJIRIKk5kaSoBayeu6qga7b9OdIZg3CQDI@7xDZ8bMdwcVriOm7FC1aKxS/jBRDIcTNeqCgglOOteGGXHF68cEKOi3jhc3CM21b8fbwQNAsEcOGVHE/QX4hwfG/GCztK4kby8bqFIF0tXgjrFGA2@StRBEiB5QatEZfMbEcU03dN6NhIqUwx5BgvheMkmnBJ0TcD/9yuOr//AwJxznKJgFmS6ROdRqTH4OlAtxFY3JzRkguiN68c7tH@n7HheghPwmAuGofQgxoei08KI54xDKUVCnhCBlFuFmbniOmTtxs8IDsideBQquTJ9Il6GukDLYXCqwBcS0wazRfxg/qaRMEr8GH5xMjz8nkrO0FylCNcY03MyBYS9XX8jkJhXU/dCMFrP1pDNHc9CYTXHQYgvJYIbUSmgw5Hi22YWN/pTzIJheKuPisah2bfeKNE7p2KRlJBtMw5weQtSoaCIdr4E3cVJxIPszYhgjCwmqnxVhb2CySLMWgs6yKaKm98kIWIzIEWbjYvTGTbXeEkOC5uUtRXzOuGgrg8SZJck2ISImtocmJg@Dz1cPBaQUMUHzd8DWIOcVJFQQSRmGEqXL46H6G/O1x/DxTqgAhTCcxSrGd3pbfV6zt72amcd8fJ3q5ADEyx3cRM5ShMYUxyGB1ENPO7eO2Wio9bOLiSzxMNsU9p@wHZwjHBPXSbHltwXKgluJeTnhdZ8LzIzifUbY2ke6kFSouGKQk8vOBhTsdFuzuvvOCzqhhDaCLb6H50BbuTFRytPMRHBXCnSM5bOR4gxLWtcdsmc6bogyJVLzAuyGn5M6zmsSeIe1qKDZdhweOwfrx7@PzgK@h019bWEqKPHo3zh60WJ1XDfpxjpr3HYX8wY9iSTaE5b1y8xnl3uj504cyWb8kSLqxBGcBrTAL2E208IWRZRJ5PtV2Ix2EjFBW4LsbNwJiQSqjqGNhlW4KuPhDE9JUlQyAJ1Fugd4pGawmckwXuwBvR6nXqvup13IxUr4teDKsmWOFO/CK2kB54Lt3byI0NX0kSHfdlu4fs5dOtU3b6tML2Xux8zr46fMFebj0/xeOyRy@2D/Z3GHwrz08qbDyjgB@8gAEHlEDXXbNp9hogsrOZzAojzDtOf8TljrKT4P4nRo89dZomrkdteEbvSYe/aLbpl3msCgxHR@IKcshoz/J9fnlZE9CRctOiU2m4hZ8BbAPGtD0c8/acltW2AFbCsW/fMr3gDBXrWlCDIG@D048priThZRC0FYguAqM73PASMIDHRRpAY3jjS@csj0cwWxoThAs/H03B08rxsxO29XyX7Rw@390/3T98fsL2Do/h9eir/eefAj33T06P97dfYBABPjvc3d/b39kiD56BjMbwQDTd6nZXFjQEJ6o0L3CJm@5hDd@is84ABho8uzLofJ7H4gMbpY9ldK13ZitelPCaGH4mkNYEWHhJGzPf4lJmsOZL@wnkFx5ddLKYYRuUGjSWMrS3omiu0O2hyWlceOiNGF54YxbpnLJC7vFFOrQpp2WZTN7BPSc4982PM1NbDlBDQguAG1EFG1BKjOy3x@OpDUJZhtSaXQeNbvHU@KZA8YJRnwRbR4oSUUzsfUGkuLN/38b5IL0YegDfg0dWJOu7HIAthx4cgK1wD1RF93EvCMsJiIF/OEDxzFa5x5tef4/Wf9la6LFt0Cg2L/LE642q1GDj@52tXr9LFvj5LA9drGN4TcuiKB7BowX7bje43a5hAsuDTBR3EeFeNYCUQdi0calBbGOzB9SwIRS4Aff9GG3fY0opobFT3Oxj2ha/2uC8a9h8S9N4Kw7xHsujsYqS2IdthXcGtPjl6sSAeI/HZD7CeLtCKzQfGg9ibt9K0RB7HunemWBL2X0Z2L6VgV8GDSBSJ0Y6Teqp6LQmonHagpUVzwGOxHnbb6LwwM6tQdOciBDcPfjGevcuIYicmhgnBfsOKXdQRXhNY4qvWbYdF9o4idUenjxBKdjsOH3f4nWoTJZgfHMUQGPHBqm9LpUnUqPbIqdStB07kmgDuHhOqg1gyoekShzPF8lD8RW09fDqKtpHh9kxGs6lGVk7S@Ei0pWJ0y@gCPNr97C3oWtUhf4pjWXHN3QVYr5U3t0@U795nULD@1ws8Mumgk2E/OrEHqYFzYPW@WgDoot6l2hpwe0N3qCBscWeOiEtsZUHyGAc2LFgXPekXgzD@Pbh2/54rGTanzzfvy/xWCpKJi6RB15HGUu3FKsGSaYoTo2JvR4R2QmZBVmvBD4pwhnK6yd4ggRroQgUsVGO0KWnk7cmCBESlK4xaINkEfciieoO8SdYmbZOBIokfZRofaRfKdulZDmRHu8cYRFyKoGITgWY8dqk8f4T6q9uodu9Gx3I74ejy9@ZO949fBS23TuxfVTe1OR8XLxbiuB6ONpv7kDLO7dfCi2UPTUfMe8kb2MLOT1kztRiLNwde3eKr2/VHbU9QIN9L86ghEgjqQ1sWqIOLGMqPEIiimasEJ2c7laOj5nMxycQF@QeDhlaQgwi7gV@qQTfPWvZJOy0UGkKB8uh8hT4TGxdC4983NGYZxJvjqgQOkhK0CMUFpNXOJLUEz0LqRC0m54EYkC5ydxdBzLIqwrEN2gKFYRXbKyGhQWUZhYzxjsfy4tu6hZ0S3HdOLonn3ZM874bL2NyR1FE0c0/xjmeFJldfy@5flwI0uEKlvl2QAVugSaN95Fq7AQS7gOgpk3W4B3VElQpbprnCnYsoB3u8MpMath/f4YiRuJKONeFI2JdKMcia1w/XgzUHNp5iN2AgVs6RSDfoQwBgYgnn41ohSbGnZ4y2QWBkonXBD2JcgVEr90Uw5tFlXE/WQoV8mhbW6TcVINc1nB2VuAuzgf6BPc2r06Lh@mkQNremZT6q0mK9xITKQU0n1mYIBAwr@Zyy/fhni5FEF39@@Lmfci0/PR7fRjfj1F6I4@m94Fz95@ngvAxA9xBOr5VPmgwUxFB1ZnRp0yUnTqjaP4gL3xeCDKDxmabHbwUaTLVBBtO5W02dt4jRbETyK0yRJpwWFDeam5R/@bu5FAg35vewsenxxsbAuEewZtfhIfrImZTIl54THTSz3Rdm8D4saSeg8fH6DTSnWfm6NAc39DKC4OBtMwWLUBbHDLi22pTwRQDJUKzihpeooaTesXpWT1VL0ZLuLd/UGFLZAWtPTEFKbtyIiJyFiz7rgyQ6KXpCOw16CjeJ14BvpCHVIASyESH8hSiTeLevBFFQFmukhV/se1TiFR9utLbXtOw0YZHSqb7hx9DRJp8rRzuJWZNqGeKE/Ehc17fViBWSlY1maKCH87jIqZJFLw20T/ST0loxV5skLzjylUjreczq@sSlc5O@aledb2WWmqWZAZ9rmH3vIF71bo4dzqXbdZl/TeNYXP07i1juRW2jPcsPeb2HvXVEp5uVRgaCMmz9QwxrMjgJtmuPJMZ08hoH64ns/Hwu7iApgjhQ2PlAp6AmOJSttQLuBBPyvmlXnW1VrJLmWKvateKeFbPT5b8pJ5U0OMxdJ4gWviCfNWvYVf6i@hsq2lfMnfQGMEoKTz7wejsB/bvOMMl9mzTfDltM5Ye4WY1PEOi2eaVEl4njZwpof4jPaJDPDqe9qbpYpxtaVmQA6B@CpRVb0i/o4T0KKMN@r5DISIhFVmIvbfeS4@CU0cZmjAAkKpVC7KzQXjGMAqu@3DfEd8NrepcG9PxqGMigqKKMUnayWeyjEcAMaPi6FW1JnmaaTQ7mAm8OPA9RWMbG/xG8RsIpkk63KlhuHTwIVNDJ65vwKNPiwmYBCnmHh3fkKD4@K6jg/vQFJRP511oo7tEiiCG4DZudk3HkSj@BhCAE/4RV6k0MYMpFCvQE/lRP5o7QHtxk@N6XEXAU5C8Uh5hYRE3T680Rk47volGmKwgE/g/ukJyclrBR5RA1entVjFC@AQHJ5LQMrR485CWVKUUVMZHdxxNiURTg2gBcIQUj@6lBk5kwejnmQnNZ8R2zG4XMs1p8WhMDnTScVyRfjJM36timrUw8zxcvRWuToRrPJxnagylQf89BipEgeTY9RjuhsljsNSttEqMdBMNarqpgcYxhi3eBetpvlO3xsDlsCo5V4YBGxMBaiTk1Yza5yELE3FCBg/Dqzxc8HdW1HyYywnYJ5Pp41MSFWTS3lixlWSKSzXb6m7yzikMQTaTGV5Rz6NjfRPb8UYpjkwKcQIKGk7jU7Mtl8ZYknogcajNyOWNJ7ImlIlNZTob/NDhrYY1o41EqERpJolwQzpfCOlQ8EIEBeFERmNByy0HkUci8iiCFqEWgmT5ocVbDRyKNt3ES3iM8T3@BI19MnMBXGx24COe8yEvPD@MPEkgEroL8mwyTUoTPPbBPUWh7uhFxmmPpjHOFhLPI5O8YZomPzLdxlnuhVBORAVFIClu0T0MEZQeA@gB@86rQgy8kX6RXpI@NUCF7nfNIdvCUYRBp6mkifPoaC/VQ1NHZHnFG/T7XVxUJMXuik48C9sc2RyupowxRpbRNGkfN@5w@BS6xPlxiKSxQ8R8hfs/xgHe4Pyc30fP0MIRiFacULF8TdqyR3y@AtrMcpafCjfZwOOLojCYP49mgtccbz1IabrMXZNAF/NAy5F4Udu8fYvpcjwWgsa2oEsrSNJ3BlbzYudTXK5d0zPLeoRkl2K1N6Mtr4wPSgGRgoBsBtTVnL4iSZGl3yZf@lURYYodYEf/BfCmeYmX5kpb0GMQoAfKqWe6l2ZLk6RjM1zjRbzIyrjwiMemnYHb5HM3oFvhZbt42tdL8dUu4DB8Yv/MV4ObtBSWknBNaryYDFV9abWQgMGBkraDi7@0HoGn@jk9MFLP9IEoSwk2mSVaWhZ5Id2lh/NMQA00SxJZegjJYDu@1YSaoYkqqQuo@CrHODF@NXgkJ5Bes2vgIV9tVgbw9MuYAkEGgpWiu/IgiTXxj8oDEwULltCNoGbSIP0caivQ3E3XAuk7JjDVCkWL5B0q@PTp/gk7Odw7fbl1XGHgPjo@/GJ/t7LLtr@iJWxcByebruzp4QFIl3CxnC@KH4KHvHUCMWUKkLaef8UqXx4dV05O2OEx2392dLAP2AD98dbz0/3KSYrtP985eLFLi@uAgT0/PGUH@8/2TwHs9DBFqQbRpHE8drjHnlWOd57C69b2/sH@6VeU4t7@6XNMDBftt9jR1vHp/s6Lg61jdvTi@OjwpMKwYNLu/snOwdb@s8quBulDmqzyReX5KTt5unVwMFXQw5fPK8eM9gBESrldgVxubcNQFVOicu7uH1d2TrFAY9cOEA8yeJBiJ0eVnX10VL6sQHG2jr9KCaQnle@8ACAIZLtbz7Y@hcJJyj1UgXrZeXFceYaZBkqcvNg@Od0/fXFaYZ8eHu4SrU8qx1/s71ROikw6ODwhgr04qaQY3ldESQMOoBaEg3v7xck@0W3/@Sn0GS@OcDtDAir5JRAGcrkFUXeJwLjLAUsLRDo8/gqxIh2oAlLs5dMK@B8jTYlaW0gF3DCxcxoFgwSBiKfRYrLnlU8P9j@tPN@pYPAhonm5f1JJQIXtnyDAPu63@ApYBxJ9QaXGeoJ8cScwqxRwboqqk@3v/X/tPdl228aSz@ZXwKAtAhJ37aagRLLsG2fi5E7sbCMpFEiCFBKKRAjQIu1ozpl5mB@YD5hPmYf5lPshM7V1owFClrJMkntPck4sEOilurq6uqq6qto6OvnyBUIupYECXr0QaiG0Pf1IcA5ruVEyjCXhFG0D/pVpQBmuvnoTYGrGVctLsS1GJzh6@tnJM5D4OH@Wnb7/AjadvVziI/MbbDT6I/zMJJgZBL35qBtOhlMMFdXV2L5xFY@qeIeDC9q5dVZ6zzUeYkahCuVyt/vlURf03Ffdrlu9T80MGHfVECP3@0q5MkbM146KN9p3njxhtB9kEHW4JseY5IaHxwtYkpG/xo5t/lXgWo3GIJBqGIOPDSsLUcyHIpj5GTkjhTLirQZpl2SAoN@hUANVdFTz9X4XraDo90iFpjH8M/kx/cF7g/ECmDNbtRoN1GEJjPBtoLrhTiizAf0jiQXCIXVZj4Pg@5HTNLtDlb8@mk4HjuuqOlQ2ATVw5Lh3VO8Fo1z1Wr4@AUuHypIQPlZqN0kw@nRZUGbJvNRnNDIH/@km9MdV0HDqBrSJUldkihbbpLPG1dHfqGpJhgoMnqBJRpHv5dHXL75CZa7Z3urk3n@k3/PaQm9AzCwL@90p1TunPx@dcwFYYJRSA1ASSqKLRsOoo7xJdOFrKHiJhShjPm3VlwFt64ASkGPn/tjsEzfjWbgwoQc2/JfPj14ef/H8OXBOhHZrb3t3p1PSSbK@rvLfb7AfynhKOcIi2MZBTKNPxip5CnIPrRQjR3ZK/kTAjQYWxCzkatLoJaZr0F4ZWT8l5GM43Biv@JigA54dIB5si/JoPCwpei1cmUIATmaoLo7myl@QhO@DqEQ0IK4q4yXN2gL/wbb18ldLXA9ICEhIjPLMAuWCckF8z36uHEFJt6E0O1ikbis65qRrGgdk6SLvWIydpV9C28YsxuyoiOuVpp1qAhAP81BYymtiwiv7r5QuROy8lOsL3nwt9AaP30g6OkpO58fJUfIK0Phc10RzdGpzlkGfSsvnhx5M0dqa7unAQmO@K0DR2hOrsc7vYawGAuUcXQY9K9dwR6cDyXdJ/q0fVlzrHVMq5uDAdjpCsfIbKLdoONJKR6UBkd8quYTFbelcJYy1a91HSRX5RqejUOjMoOkX4YPa/x1xUtD@ASic0HqKLSNl370wSa0yrkB7JaSE1@o8wTjESLFpvvombebGnJhLPTA5pFlw9AygQGZnqV58Q0kKh04BApDI0a5hrl/tcHbpg@b0oe1KdTwOmfSvIseSvUJtFSvtnldJ5qqqAxT84VouG5qM7j6BitaH7COXiMIFXKy3tB7HNrex0XJV7o7GOhk99Con0rxkR9Q8OTVlaanFL2mSjF1moLMdgSh6c@uJ3LplZLHMMHw51XI7ZnZLc8CCNujzEAEtHDd64LMrbjZbImdFf00Z7DBRNurMuBVJurkeOV2OA2zn8YAsI3j3aHKN28WYW6c0e2lrlvOYnEKwk9TDMM0RiMzXrQPWaZO91tCTmRLpVUP/xYRzzQds4lIl6pzMQyA0Q@Pr1kt/iTCP7zduO@18A9F6mO3/xYRSD/YT3imjaUyaO/SCmv7jOMWIcsOBfSjFkvhf2opGw@tauIA/1FdNRq6SOILOQAkmi4T@m1sVAsovmT0hteyziTYiPeGNzHusxBd84rWrn77BJ7EzezAoAA7e4HGqiEEIMspNeIS3utoIPswN91UYzAamWQ5204EfoQWIxO/phLZdZb2SDHJ9P4mDJUih/Ua4aFAbXefj6eWk@3Q69kfhNPRBV8Dk2gtegPi4pEfM/zmaTa9juoyFPgyMQoNl@swZTDijF/7WR2MdI8tTnASRY56IJ7Pl0SUnIiDjLbqZWZpnUhLVKJ9uS9fZ2k4rlbIRjuTx1XI7t9bdbBVV5sNjbECW1WHusJ6jFBMKfTHCGzsrBXrvK2DA2LNqlu/e4hOWgXgfUEQnARmIFTArJ@DmIFA7uBXi08GiOqB0djNM5ROcBHidSezQ66qPV0YCp/8AD6WfWK29plGVDfkLTGmHD8vb0d3e/Z2hBwB@AfitzSJqKSIESug7VPl8YpaZJS8lwEIOaOhWWUVNAJTk6SwcgWI7zjTaXeRbzX5e3oYNcjKBrVkytq1QJa5IB4RvvLjL6QLL6S5d68cfrYpVcSkzBO6IR4nTvJ1gg7s8NGnx4zkiG2@QMT2Vlh0D6NtQ1Qcs4X2BOQdOE2TOwnv3imm37ztrOQR6RU5Nxt0Bjq32S4pxEJkHT1amM2DGdg574m1QiZNpVLkn9m7lHYVJvopw3XfdO11Nmdi8xUZ7fUCo9Zb4uOyU8vDkiCaLMXJqAhpCFYqeNZnnkbjwurjevO7yDjzchrPURUdvKnq@B7z2cVN8gz6jaqPRS4pgx3yXHf3@tAsD797OQaRNFvG7xDG6yDK6S340msqhSWPp/hgi6hPYc/gYAOaw3wHgzpyfW5Ga98dS2TPVp0y@RMQnpvrGsEDgS9EQz/8xERkfkWgmxVnNgyeY2JVOk1q1HuarxQ/cIAarBLXUFsJWxHSycnRE@eSHThcdVlrIieDp0Dxk12niNcIoj7sYGOTQvbustc473NJCtwSyLJV6X0sqohl@nnYX1MoKKmCJF6BCj2iFN13ef1S/dCxQDlrg2vRZfEmbVRyMa20ANPCP@am7QBk47UpqZlZUdiF0iTXAWgA1ZDQOWHtC6S@cMcXjAbssIxDt@bWDfzakBiaA3mlqbGOVxWCJRVxBN68216odcpWUoPg3ol@WIou6pC5BAwFDDPW9FrSAGTIJejRMU3IXk/IygMocQUWvhcsSXlKCzdSlsOA7IlUKbG0bJZpFJfbNNmqFjYBgUVwmBQRkluIiaSuw0RXCYpTYLR5PWgIEYkX7jHGYCpmVLA71zDEC4ZGg1RzltGVVm0LB9HFr28181PRNX/ebxtdm/ivgR0N4Wmvlv@41M18z3bbb2aqZmoAP1@w18xFQ4ZoAa67wy/6j4Acze7Z2SzSUjIyUIa7AE1SlrlFvq38XWwcU9qtkDNWeGXus1K8uX8qRye/9/lzelmSK7/zywSrfSAWIJJenxGcqmsJhfZAEVht3ehwVKroqlZuOgFcq7XRoffn6@fNMXtHeUrm6XAWz7WaziTTcM9OoKy9etF@E00a2dGM4H48b0fXHsy97DWL9eBX3OJ4@UQp0ADMCayKuT2cjvkoAYYCiWLomkZKo6s@HQzNnPx6S4dzBrHFJCbe3aP8JtdvFl6/JwENNyv56gQPE8V1YevFd@yxnSivqJARqo1PqG1sd4AB68MUQPYH1YQk1hnxZ@dPAtuV6h@9wA8GrMGiyKBGu@y51kLU/CsbjadX6ajobDzAU/cFNvsLz52aFJhfBQy4KH53HlPC0agVvwrERuIpFTFLH5tS@pC4mUBnGMcv658Ho2SJy7NNvbdhVYMgbOMwNzHRcteyR7Ura8Xs0y3QIYN@r9JUfOX3CU74w7PSygNMngGizVS1UfTJFXLpiRHB2d2lEajG4dcoGAEN3SRRQWdFpemkktxTXyLXPFq0h4rDJbQhMmNTjfjUwlun344pvkuHwfkyREsrzxP7mDJEs0rQCZfkBPjEf8z/VYFk/z2WsYPkGr31Y5TtYoYsVSqXHfe@Ha@fo6Mh6FG1sWEdHx/BQq1lHx0fWCb44PrZO4Pcx/l7z2tvbHea5J@47eHmsXt5Yx9AGGTg3@pezE/gJ3zwMTEJ/YZziRw3vUbXzqOsdHHbixunRMcaNw9Pf/u0//vbv/9k4kh//hT@O6cfpt7pQvV5vPOq/e7R208HfpyfnlUe900fReWXUQSpDdv/FLPbHvuHAWO@X7gjSGYzD3m2BO9qDI4zJWxA99hz4x/NAA/vxR346S9LHWfqIaTnT6v44uvSpukUtHHqVo8raGjwdeJV/qZDtRN77@v1beG@5yMspbp9Qi1fPWEevnr54YWa@Rq5P0vswwDQteGuiHJuEkziEQV2U1Z1ztVOrXrfOa9aFBg9dDbpcMAsiq5kMzL8KkGp05BdC56eiNuDBKJm@2SLP5yRX8YjkO2U65/u3fNFUHg@e8KEOtbEBDA/Ld9hdWkIvcfgALp7CeLXT1s72ea1cLpf0nVzdPrE56i2ivvQdTeoYl85gOBIogiUDY6c70jzEBTSIyCiX6camtT7fLOZMULUmjYkV7nLFkOfR3kQDKWk2xxZujudHGQsVProFy4rnFAiAssHyvkdKAABFeB0Q47L4yt04CvrhcKmP3fFShLR32CsxamvdGq4EbVn2rGfLuB4O0wYBISgFULoYbDTfICNvCmVD4nY8RvUbxI1VorqQ/NPWFk2wdkqJpuPlaAydOeTOE18DdwLMuzJZ44mK5sIeuGYvGOJ177yiecJSd1KEuxegKWLSBwVzgFcUjTEtFAt8fARJCRFhPaCEI1eUDTEawRlP2IllOoRH2PAxkIuvYyMy3MAtVQgKlVpUjtUVZ8IH1iPXtSIuiViF3@kBMJEHmSBJH5a71jJHgZErNfHtgVBahLfLoSIt6SldWUk2rRV9AAtS5RUekOHhGCAFS9bpOitgDUvrYjy50OPnI7UYb8Sj8zO@cI66afMZOXAs3Y2K2Kbu2B3dZuMqXX418RNBbzSN47AHyEqWapooCx/7r8@g1bNKiTsTasGDOkQwvlqP9Ioyx6dIKVhEFCLO8D5A0@5EUUGmIB4r4pkYnw2XMyfFk@mkRiy3FyRhn534uPeHihdHeExL3vsE2O0dgfLAB5VqgqmHM5XgRs4oaarTdghP6C@P6/9Si94@4UzMvMKiJXYBANLEoWfnLEVS2qKmBGogixSBkVyQBYMPMoQ5DkZhkqlTlSQA7PnMo7hRqMdFfoEAm9jNYRZ99WlV9ox95kLwrdwDkPGqb8Bo91yJvy2iPTUY3NX47kNdk4dEIV17q/Sh@ZECx4QaVjCgD5dvNTtDtLniXkd5zDCb5CBLqlY6C@/tgRoXEJlfrFOMCTUg3CKPk9opYKOdwwaw09wySLlwM9O8QcBI3OZOTjwqh16eLhYJVpi3ohcFKRLBTUlHlbz7/@43M5W9GYbIwuKDUkgHsEenbg46lUO@ycIVeB0oQV3yswFrnM0xKRq7T8iOgllUQl6kRqcajlxXaugywzWSlCJK0QE/TyvmXOaqqvGmtc@ztWsVjip6p2KLHEPSiVwJOZKvD3gzb@1sq3Y5aIiO3ujXjYpukuAg7TOhZkdQTturP0T0oBcGXfOjJ@emiDSUDq@4vBqzSBYgXGYap7boiEbKmZ4oBUhiX4WjeTJ9kfz6Mj2lN5azPv2SbvwEucAHMVhEBN9tyBM8oges@2upBcgHQmAE7EPlxwE8l0oseYiGab@MR8fThdOsntlndrW1s@/apCdrOazcj0EzKvcDTtiFtwaK7kmJAcmu/SZgFj7rhYNBMFHpQKGq9KY/daXZUzTnv9PsLuZLVm1i4oFt8PK4BpNILwTX9BzN/NGVT4@fTl/P/OUL2ITo52cTns9X2N7nsBnhtUD05XNeo0cDEDXsG9STU5q41xApZMkHyaefkGjAyeAMcaEAAcEKArhPPf44O1gDDeb42XahpWfaN2FSL1hCidmR94IPTi5KfOfsFV6K2uV3QJuOcSmtPNKn3E3JIiPgB@VjZrzlGizqj/GkJ5hkziFU9lohPL65mGtVrTEQaFOpXO8fypR9ci809PGFKDZJ/7J7NR8noYxsZVhqXFgpf/0uqZPqxuRbruAlk2Eed8Y4sN3TEFZpqssQo0qxIEqYasXQHxW6afxkdkyFBlFVOPNEe4voo3nTec/csHR/qFQNTAxhHNgo5RTHWTLUDajdKaX7rKVH/TCjfCAcgBQEYz2iu4@JNd@Yc4wzjKkriJnoyf0tdPa/ZyWX39BpQ4olpZdi9CuIDMzDUl2fPNurVlMOsQ2tFiiFL7@eXgWi2Yo6YSivxsVlnM/xd1dY79DcMtKfgSrlOWzKLg8zCy0jHCqXTQOdWoihndmcBRqrKYyYkgSxnEhi8xnP0tINB0YXsg1WSqAkw5wXspXEpEdawN6giZXNs6rFiJVPrpLetARERYGmBoqpyu6Wbmxy6TVa9dIdTMGalSlNkd1KN9BUZi1QwjUZ3ImoYBVRrZ@HKIarCE/85VdDUxYBWSzdlEpF5KtZh7hmmWtdR7Gs8CVC3EMtCOfaKBB0e2PMW5cClm8OL40XyX5fCcPr1tEI2GJWFmYPaz99x1oPK5BxLmpZG@LYK34@w7yuZZCuSvA/5tgFLnWFBp2MBQRE1kZJF6IYJcQG4VtbIyRq3mqU3ZL4DDXKfFNNa7flUif36AmDQH@BeM9sEI9ihisBWLihkMixbnUliO3u3Y/2ulvM0pnxFZqkgSOnRmlmz@tRhM7kd1mpG2XJpuBY0LzlWj/TQE22kjbvQWjnaZRLDwAEljQwrRt0RrU3xMAbBzAMnRSSzbmpGxbrh8rQ/UeyfyscK18FoQAtIDSVdIDyGd1CzBMsEgIFU9ICrTyOK4BqHcpR2EsqqpG4SKjNULLawVuyVRcahPSs0C4dW@klnrPEsCoWWk2VhcgqF1azHMxyidYMOjoK@mgI11aq2DXswWJ2aEDbcik0gMXBerrJDLsyh7O2ZglsZLLOyRiFin4GUQxHBhlnE2bOedIFJoQvCfGypcAy0VJfVGh/4AJSIl2da8WCCLLXVA5JLTSNFO/zicZ8MXao6vvwQ8EQ01yQC@GEOKpOP5JCU/qpCM3j8w4iJYPe3w@V/qSZuC@pytXRt9Ei78W7Ld6Lzb1nGTfQ2oC7D/4N@xxrSsGN6f5jrZsBwA94/yUzBfzDBErxCokOZAduHyeuXHf9INXr6nHS5Zu7NftFPU5c7gYD2I6B2VJkUxX0xIR8kCwDz8rBloLcf9KGqZR07l5YIaiYCEpeM5PaqV5mkWJmqL8qMp4wNZRQ4gfQHLkXUTQhHl1N@xybDhsUfh9SZDrptS1Wi1Ah4oqn@FNC/B4MOVPeUFYyj8Ba70q3MgaBhwbBMtbxzE/uJWKlR3LssK8vr8/TYVwvWS9@ukh2H7ls/d5yWXmdbNrrqXi2Xo5Attj8mW38tnJaaqCFdmwNuY0LlQz4pHIAimGCxuhhnBrzhWuZR24/X@z7U3z5o24M63948WVdo7@fFWLWUyGmXyjEpAWkVh8Nb1RPlyf2AMt2Qhryuog93N802x@sG9XftLA/vgzcSstJ5Sl1i68Luk2up1JDE6p0SPbHwo6Q1/KavrBlbV9YzuqC5vlOt@HNP7fhf@xtuKFxgQkv79hpjKn/c@7/EeYeUyiO95p7ze6vdu6r39kmYdm581bLsh9arcMPds8WJ82zxf7WZz@Uk/Jhu/HVDP4m5R/KO3tlfoQH@LWpfr0pH5YPsNjOTXnZ8DwPHqWVo@fQyuHHuk0stTyAfw63Vbs7y/JhzaPqP5YPd@Ch1W4DJGeLZ/tni70m/m93/kjih3m6ooWP21qNKK@KbAh8Figu8qSWT@O0yafG7vACSUCp41kDKe780GiNAEbnmUV7rymyChAQ5394E8gVUFcBXt2lzVOUwyShPBoccaHyP4ivHleCFaC7cOEPdUG7vYheac4JlW4CpYQUaOvicX0Hj64vJA2FBkAnniAxk125Qb1wqGNMsYV/D5sf2DoxxRNb8lbYpse/nG3Krrgnu@L/lq1omVxOJ@2CxOpl6ylMVxJY38UMSzwJoyhIWOIfBZMAtmQ0podTFHTwprc@3os3Dr9n978nqnGrTw11v4u7HJvDDdWjpWU/@hBWVnhFWtFbWJXqGc/HdrbUL2DceGcYxsmo6JpRmFzOe5QT//Vs@SL5jDJRNDCvdsJZKRogy/UaVz46DlAm@RhIDEoAO5jNJw26WwwENoyVwfTvV/73ABreZwpDG3ShGBr7v3fo8tA4iCjEZTEc2nRTTzAevAoif@Zz1jT0mp/7o@AFJoaByYgvbVSeytanFFyTmNlxtbJEGAc5XK5kqnEGK@L9cUWFfxJqLQvDjenGGBvj1IUJEe@26xQ1AbVsDi2gW6qH02mSlueocV2BfmZrUE4wmCQODcHDwXREwM1x/BsKiA3LkhcER/pTOk1fUEcEzcwK8SYHHFUwmV8R7eibVU9bT84lb5rXMm64Jo/XvSdyq7ltI0JxmsTY3NrDL3P2vaRzyZKkDtDjAMGaIYGCPCFzOi28Ak0hjqe97yjvD3IlWJBIf3X1TZY9udHDIxq7J8HIJ15x3QsTKjAIYyqANRujtyC7M4qqGVLtzUdxndcCBVaEcTwPtnf3tggg2vFV0cG0nynabkDLM3@2bBBwl8nVWI9iP7m0xsGbYCzeKwQ2ZZTlRUl0hpdq@fMxubXsuEQ6gMrMSAELzn6V3508e/7J0etnJ1UQU7axeExhSbqsYyCXP2/Q9@EYMzUwGWEVXr713s4WE7kTVysfokWOQf/QRPuGCbBqII7ruAeEkVPxqJr4WXDDVoRq@2RU1cfh19PZ9zpxMS43BGVOtx3YCrlq5ZfLGNIVY19lJMFMYgOogwNTkduzMTCelUK38grAgHC3bgIUOUb@iZRrHzys1fSaekJPNWCstdohG1nsp@MQFM/K5/NJhttWaO34VgWYHB7/M2t7WCG@ULc71qWHenyn7zU7Om7vjTN33@lbkYcIhcOIez09Xqr5c@YSmWYDQlzyclYhk//z3xW3c5Mm0Rk7iYvZ/623nkpeXGem/oyvS3UqcR8mK4Fqb@tJsEiecrZJL@noCr3pYCnX3j8FrXrgvDX7iBz3HezVGxt9z9t030GXswizUEbADIPX0KLbwXfDzDsdItY4O5vgHcjrGLr39ctPPoIpRz@xIE5Ovz1ff9SoViqu28Eh@B7F95189vKvaOWfuXWy9j@fTa8ELzNfd1KH2b6KT5vnBH3VxqE1cBUC5xwFiYw@Pl6@9kefgrTkVHxAAbolUWAcTEp44Et8WQd9k1DmwvtBTBx5dnZybffdyKNSl7Ng2GFbxU3svXFGbieBP5dmF9vQhdduU@sJVPLQqymH9XACu/VHr19@4lUOfAtb9QpWRWWjp4kDCIUIxsFXR3gjUoZ0gKsQVSUcrUcEA/9tVOzD7FgOGv5hpXNzcys8n3BOVxB@KikBD5x5VShu5q1OaWeWUsEyCjx8wVvbX569tqtQF1Ow4MsJbm9LYlocxOqpPpjckFPQFrh8hWU8b2ttjd5hlXnsee1m08WMKDfQWoxXmEOzvLBmnZuZ7w0cjUg/Cgsu7GnX2w0OZIkbrZ12c3v3g@kMtggP70Rfi4GFeKi1vAmT5RrIhoGnLv9ZAzkZdlPv4db63mfh8T9/vf9q58Tp9z5u2VX7u5jc9meRCcDMv66zWAQ8dib5XgkIjFzs@43I/37a2Bo0@yB5tnYHwe52sNfc3OtvB5v7vf39/f5wa6832N/1d7f7vQbmG6cq9atwAlKSzeSP3Q7v1@1tgtleu7k/HLZaO7uD7f3hfru5ubnV29seNLe2hnstf3NzZ9De6@333i@1pfCUgMEqvot7R54DP75duCut8Hap7f4f)

Klein 000 follows the path of Haystack/Reng/reticular, barring its trip to the underworld (`/` on line 1 sends it to line 1157).

**Code in polyglot:**

```
ln
247  #/`[[[[?"271"]]]]@ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
248  #\* * * * *|!o51     ~nJ     ; ;#p'34'   \
```

Pure reticular code is `;p'34'`. `#` fixes `;` in Reng as before. Two `;` destroy LMBM marbles from line above.
Reng code is `~nJ`.
Pure Haystack code is `|o51`. `!` skips `|` in Klein 000.

**Klein 000:**
Stack is reduced to single `0` like in other Kleins. `?` pops `0` from the stack. `"271"` pushes ASCII values to stack, interpreter should be called with `-c` or `-A`.
Placement of `` ` `` is dictated by Pip. Spaces between `*`s are for Retina 1. Note: `@` must be on line 247 because of Gammaplex. `#/` is not a problem because Agena comments don't nest.

**How doors work in Klein:**

[image]

**Paths of all Kleins** in a square program (picture from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/klein-topololyglots/139202#139202)):

```
             ^
            I|P
            ./.....
201, 211 -->.......<-- 100, 110
            .......
            .......
            .......
200, 210 -->.......<-- 101, 111
            .......
             ^   ^
             |   |
            000 001
            010 011
```

**Paths of all Kleins** in a program of 32 chars x 7 lines, which is more close to polyglot proportions (1157 bytes x 251 lines):

```
             ^
            I|P
line 1      ./..............................
201, 211 -->................................<-- 100, 110
            ................................
            ................................
            ................................
            ................................
line 7      ................................











200, 210 -->xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<-- 101, 111
line 32     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             ^                            ^
             |                            |
            000                          001
            010                          011
```

Klein interpreter can traverse space outside program code.
For example, Klein 000 will eventually enter program code at line 7 char 2 moving up.
Klein 200 after falling out of the right edge of (inexistent) line 31 enters the path of Klein 000 (line 32 char 2 moving up).

Comment: I'm glad Klein 000 was finally added.  I had been trying for a while to get that to work.  Hopefully we (probably just you) can figure out how to get the last couple Kleins in.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic I want to look if more Kleins can be added without making polyglot squarish. I really don't want to square it – too drastic of a change, especially considering that we already have several Kleins.

Comment: You can do it as long as you have a ratio a little above 1:2 (height:width).  You need to redirect the ips down towards the "bottom" (the middle of the Klein square) to split them.  I don't know how feasible this is I did try a little bit to get this to work.

Answer (score 7):

## 292. [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 13620 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                         @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#
#  
# 
#  
# 
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
  
#ceppp         ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu1&&1&Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在 16 5""61*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]R 8ogr 
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";   print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQfxINDNZpP3cm53s4dk374zIBpdAApAXQJVaFSBBJpkx8ysPdZI8lqenVWMRru6o1lrLVkbsfKG1xp5pd0I6euGYj/pB7QeDofCofkH43NOZhUKIAB2j6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4abu/nP4/gw545/Wm373jMM12PtUfWhTlS2cMpe2BYbk7PSBKG2h11xwPT9tySFGEaY65njDzWN@zu2OiaLAKuOpvZO1bfM0dJ5poma5p95xL8M4zZ5iU7tFtWGyAxzzk3beuNOQK/LGOPzP714NpjLWcwMOy2y4Yjy/bIN8fYMwMsnXHrnBlN1xsZLc9ybPDKM/bc7huDZttgFHw4MnmkbQagWucUZ96nwNgTZ@SakILTMl3XQcciOBojy3m8@/SThfBamn1iAFLDvjlZSF7T2AvLHLUXY@js89ODg0XXDPtMcWx2cBslLct2x55z6C3Cz7HdrmkbTFeLqr7omQdiema/kC6k57zA78AaQWkaotRKs5Kxx4OmOQLiiyK8tLyeChFOHU5w5tj9KTMnAAxw7EAw02MWlhbLpdMYEv5PzJZjt2fgwckEOADXHAy9KVOY7QgeAC9nxNyh0TKVttm3BpZntlnfAuycjsDGZVDg7NycXjojKHiFsyIh4g7NltWxMIrIgSshsz0ym@Muc8becAzouaxtuUazD8GaU9Y2O8a47yVZE/yAeOR@2TNtgZJldzEfL2YuCMGGKsCx39SANla/zwCdc0QHk3bZDnpcojsGbZqEpdlGUPszcgEko@/6uZ9PeC4ZjPds5HRHxgAYtW0SDT4/fMbcljMCG/wwLK8F68C0DI/t7LDo/tNHUVYNyKiOmlJA0gq7YoxFfE92YfTHpssGxhTStj2oXMyh8vNjSBCcRTeiJRbNZJieZtksy0JlKzA9l2ZQJYpggFqrZzT45ZleYFkN@D4XTWI6nZHRtfomh9J1@h0EtI0cq@eYDu90Nprkvi1KY5tlCiy/zbZzbBveRVbUIRGEmGVaMQe/PPwAQhEw0OCXyfKUArZAdoIssD3WMQZWf8qhD4cIvsVyGtsGiICmBpD1AkAo6ghh/gnD83pA2J5xASCVvnWO4sIMJAaWVgo@qa2tFIkslI08Sbdn9vuYKhAKSJQrsG1INQ@ZzkLKQEe9oPuZ7/Yo@4TXdhp@gOM25LgA5E0DpdJIqm34gR3EkA7yRgfhooO80DVw18GcQagQLg9@eSirfEBavU20BekKcTUkJgoUDWkA0RgUXSbLoPCyULwZLN5chgGegMB2noFMKWiskGWFbQbkKqYZkF4DZLDsNZBlGiChITAoUg3KVANENGAWDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9eLM9YC3PQcZDKXIZ7T81B42@AHxNIBVx24RQds9QL4Y9wCEK6ALLntE8LoD3sG0gJKABkZWA0IkgOcCDaEB7O@neEsRaGbpme1pBsJahVvAcMSx5ceKAFAmjCDYQMKDDjjnlggAeMgkOaF1dg1@8BFIENaBpiRbaG2o@Tw4VieinIWminTucCGlKr/XDIuiYjmCFtRkFdtczRiGBYaWzdJwsQdN13z9Rjb2hleHZBOJgjWjmH1AwSo6hgetQPwjbqQ3nQe7c7IGVD9GqCw6DvOcIXYBdF0iYA@dS7NGeozyWUMh32Q5@BuAiHGRh@QuTRIHyB1IZwqRwgiYbxWzwKAlBTIVWtktoj2IusQOwMSeB7FEtOr9zII5WGoWciwoQNC1cU49rjfL0FzZ7ZYpppqmxcpdOFNx3yTgTj4jQm0hwJE04C2nBpTxCKAdE9XqZk69UvWdQbzWePi5TDIes/CJqB/aUyh9DogWcyJMQCNg2GzbkPDPQCO4SWIJeHyhueQtR076gVQLkfQvEKmg5wAyD7RxLMGJuhjDkTBEs8S0ijcCLPmFFiZqJVVSR3jmCwQSpUWCcUdsiEHXlmgYWuPW0g1TNuyiYOgQXCptaoCXK50qmiAKjcyjTYPhtoFYhTSj6C1M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbBW3HVZmFaiEwfNfpAI9REw2qBkSdpdOivGPOA6eJ2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4ZuIN@AmgdpAvQxjpfWuwNePZ7Luu3xqPRlE2GUADWAEJ5LafTAaZ9Yw57AIIN2qw1bUGtNDyp7ZDwaQ0XchvYNk0IY5uQ471n32BdEwgNjXEHkCQmn@E@HBL2RAXD5g21bQCREPvWcEoUATBBjI7jqOjedkyX2AMUmaCyY2Ku2aXKADWrMxM/A1Q8gC9BGbCBW0HWiAqF8DFBaWlmMClR7p@YNlSWFvAhVHMoOVRFd1kH1P5QO416ndFqmUNPcIZDAsyyQ7rM0QHqMuSqCGCq25M2H4AaNoeBBEEln2lCjbdxTnIVdXxSsQyUrqJvAc25bQbaK@OypD@9lTyEuFhIXX6FYeYweCWvwGFIlQAVOxILYw@FB8pDq9VD6eehfCEFA@rXaHw7@@AWTn40YEonSBux0UDQSGoqcEI8VsNQ4Ne/DUgd9hFWdc4Bg8453AHacAdLIDsBkv122FVNGSqIwbuADhzbWQIViBnAxSDzPlQWxIwnKDCMfsCMVF3cuTJCET3r9mLTBa3mcOiMoGZweTNFIcaLLMRdDu@ixILWIQ5d5vnGFBqJKDbxnse7W8M@dIGoimFNBVXSACEB8osr/yDuHJ5iCGGq9QRL4HdJwp4zE7Setm2iNmqMphwIZA8aZEhoyqzRCCTgBTYLvNXxmw@V@BRaAaPdRqGK5KB6v5i4ihy9N25ak8UeRgsd1S9d6cIYsQ52LkagZkAlikU7bjReJneKGfKSU87QS1FU/pYhIAVSochjHeivQBtwAILmZGq3YvJcFZOTTB57nYIcBwNG5FoZ@5ox9Bax@xLckGkG51CvyVZmXWiwFQXeCroRJuiRUtHDGIFmAZUQFOxisd002DVIjxFTJnsUGzVC@mpqNkjLtNtBWoIQiEs4vypPwh21yKCEGjTMAQannFMjMUfA96QERZTBIZUSTSc6kH7H/UiT4Y5jm0YGWIwrH3F2FWjn0ADECBkL1A2rZXkNoaDcu@erKhuVCjAb6E8gNtvxsF7vD6GoIKkhsEr6h0hE9ZwTD@tGLA75xcA3HBtQlIBTK1V25fVGUOPIfiNBICCrZCMn@4QV5fzUOh@3FwvaRkcMJGOtAzXJanlyWYJ2n9eGyjqqRueoCnp/FKmKzIvxCfQt5iVXLFBZBBuZLiq8FYFKqIRjiIHg1aUk4lGF24yh96atvlAJuAkqO5dGTUD/XHTSA0GUFDqBX2lv1VQOBKsDh8Oe7Z5@WhF1kXummpZdmnPoOy2jT86bGFz24z4@fHi8e/yNxhIYfatZWnRIWdlCHpva8UTp2uNUVtVLm2EYM8CPGuthY8T5MLIkvJniTEKq0rQFjcvEJ@fR8WeLJAFNCMlBKYAZfwsqDQ8DSpfUNNzeQiPMuokEJBlE8cMy5ZD5MAMDoo7@ho/Ps/GbN1h4i0gNhTti1h8bHIDvmDq0/Xgqei4oYL5Xs8NbRIoLCqhl49DnzBQO6ePzCSrMi8iQFh1imU@ODvaPKwS2Z7jnZr@vUJCU64EuZYzaKvB8f9w2pWVhQPyBqcUS6gxxVKUJ16UEbrXmCDwrW7YCPgDA3o3qMKU/8LPm9gD3vcW8kavSCjiA7ARhUa8M60OtD0U0hAc2cS3s5C5rRclj1lgFTktbrMB3vtlq5XLmdrYYbrZaszTbYaADUootx9cbR@B17iroos60SKFWC/RPHt9C3CUlEroCio@Z22cqpeX2Jey9KBaLuqk96Jw5fVN9QRJPZnI8lYr6Y55qy6XuZij8/sTyYuk4/2pxCAup7@4e6o/8wGKMjsYuqNOAvW9smUYdnGNoucAjttN3ug7bgjhcO/QTBLVpZTZ3u459q4QMdMSsRnDSAuQvDtUYQ2hrrDfUZ6RY4Z4qn/AwbPcSpLSWzyCRiEIEKkXh1S@NCwPINcv3yeE396ER0XLpdGBO0wMkCMUhcqGpFXIlB6ZAQqrAZ2kGgwmMW7Xd91BCMwiYaSHogoi7M@@ljiQx1dTS8EtQ4rNKoTCoUKM6bjlRl4bgUGbh2Ic7hEabho5aWAIudvs94Hw@SMPHFzzQp7EAoFsVxVExw@VjDxBJzCX48UEPCyDQGFswvmQHcyhQMhSLVG/okoPqjYMgvdngASr0wHGQIOGEHQuQDjaNBXZB4EJknpFdnhGeErnMZ@kcuhw2QmuarKA0LY8P3TnjEY7RW@1w3iB4RudhABplLlRmNJgPfXw@eMIjUy5AwTNA/QclH7oJIDlpOMqkLBh8IgD1PBfHn6DrklZwPBTgK@zBXs@wWybvCyoDVJCYMtxnUW@U2lW@mTKUN8Cga@QmZn43PC9FhX7qE4BGGYKJKeoBidENkjzOgAK9oL4Uej70mzJpOPV6kGOlxWSj4gxNe1Gf49peLF6m6ZNoVP3SsezYVXRjYyNailajSTDdB9MOmu6jKQGm@2RSyIThVDRRjCSZ0LdGMdCtHr2p@ZAn8TrywASlwhtrGDNqpVKmnjRqmvjq@I1DUQDlIbSCH4ATjVcqaIzH5eoljsBC2xzK@x7yzklrZA0FCb4GlZ3bBQ0yRARQ3bGlHpll1DvXU2RQGYFCaGLzERtFz2rps/rZ1Vk7cXYTTWLseNmogO4Xg/RiA7U7csZDEMq1bEnR6vF4LVOql5uVaDq6FYsVlD4kZMTjHxfiCYPTOhaFXmc/dnYWBZIK6tRavRHBmyT1eDwgFOABPYo2tE2xqHpVgPSb8Xo8EYW48WgS@gKVaBTo0kIiuJRp1PY5Ex1A59LF8WXosYaHCkmY01AzVtdvmsPedBQOEPSooQXF0bHZHBtUBpqlDDdsb3j8sLCe0@L9No2Hg4YLO@YoC4dTLq0ljulZam6@128VLpTOwPGM1OcqKERBIrKbim5EU4qSkhn5cEiU7SeWi1XYsE1n7IZHEZYObmDq4HraG4Ow9CfDk8BV1lAyWz2HRTcfAHQWjN5ig4AD0QofzvYBtFsq/FCInh4eMRwDNW2PZoktkIs4g8x7XBohwUWPP@6Wyw9fq0FqZYrD0piQ1bWdkakASSCGRHO6tAJAqjIxUXxIvdpbY47Cdw@SJKXaMkEiHvQdg2jLxXVomHc4CMUH3RuiHJttqQ/yowPiUeVlMTLbqS2J5lycUQ9aCMgNSmI9KK2B8Eg57rCtehOIKsVA6Znz5JobqJWXrK3rer6V65R8P@QKIHYPCgk1ThvUV99L0cAzLgp5n3f5fP376dGjfd4vSo3dEfWssI/cGDjtcR84mOtEx6bdTbJ94CfLdgYWkMGP/@a8f@w4HtfgwbKq18UVYmsw7hvUn1vscq2N13KaTp@6eeuizsKPR67RN3gH0/fd/fzJ4dNnz09PKmopFChlXAwEZQ7DkwI0D@IP4rqcxeTNnIwtkL9aBAWG8Mijx1isFQFq@@7b6O5XDhzpFO4FdB/gOhHQ/4WuT9bAUQQsUkBcO4JT7sLxSkvfoPtKTSkIp1G4S1xFEsL2StPJ/cLrdOacM@R8rqCQ6c@cs@TM15DMaXJhlHI8EC4omQsTBpSnMMG6ksVwQgwFc4A9s@@P8x@DioFj2dBK91ERss1LHGfniztMt4Wa89gmWYsD4azVM0burc4F1I6hwkNLkQ3ieGiNUqiDSJspJgaiysTzoNzzCQSXy0EHFHDq4@xU@YwSMIY14tMXKT5EttkAEDvVsj/dvyoYphSNBsEIKuEGMSibNK92K6vBLKlLI18SRSlLbqr28myip5WzyfZ@PeUSETpMPjubfJzWv5CTDBdlbN5Ldc0yJreSWmTno0WtHggAlpjMkwzKYWx3nH5b4UPTUP6AMY09u8FcYLAshEQ3uFgjf0WIhbPMYuUOCL7QYpJbcBeKrno7QGj5SQAIasMVuz5PXlyzGrRFF6o77Ftend2ontPoYea98cheXKjClcPRyJi6kphKrrDd408@r6XrHII0MHC4ucBLa@KvcwKNFjQYXE4GJpwQ9yyPmmia@bMwv5oKSE1oZBLQBxg8gTILEhI5QtSvzetZXjqmB0qUiZi700GSmfEbtdM3PM@0OW/xMf/V5OaDsyKZCiV/X4z0lViahkNBZbTQD1Ass5PTR/vHxypwqBuL7uOwaQmqndHqgeawKtM@JcOZL7GP21H2McaJM0wFqhR0CxoiPjBvGZgbOgaQOoqCrjmKgWMcRzxb4EyDzBSRq06CQLisoeURjQJgMTMOeSJgpaX4P7d5H0jgWWJRliBKArlj90pAWyuujm3rtepCI0EKJQSJ8l4krWGrbMZIfG1qceKfkTXAGRvo/JA@B3mo1dgGSDcKLbPKW/ayllaK9cQmq9fLfB4OIqJ2TmvixPoqQ9CTD1qTgBQ4H4r@VWdhlZ2fAo2vYCyOnwY8Kwm@BWRH4@b0di2VN3U5HiCrvAEH7ikvIrlkFRhH0V97QCKElirMLzmYX9AQytZz6i4vrN6E7PgIBPnByYIYzyXbqDAtHvcx44BeGCPsBJfYM8d1rWaflpd1@hZfqhE01iVBGAHJp0w4uTJWDKIb1meoZ1gYszWFfKWeoAT5U0MDfSLMGTnE4uwKiUmk1JGK7PoaHWS2qTNiAxmX9HH63vi9U5CPjx1A9rFYohjWOUhoiElkFB1nkux3w@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@l@MXi8tgTtcXpsWwMIcWXsSl8lI0yLBa23VGq0FxZA6Ov6O2QcaUwXzYpeStoMJ9BccwLKDR6rWNybJBa474xmpnWsPgMD3@aYdWItWg2RF1uOX3LxQrdXyU1/ZUxs7RwISG9QrOf1jJKtqEjiu24EpiWSwGn5eGKsRVs9R4yja/UwvVwIT5RnVXEajmX@FupQfSgM8zfyxu1N0uxeg/5pPRbfQOa8pUtwtz4IY5P3sGrl5Zr0ms5Yc@XIuq1@kvd52uBPzIYHum7i7Ndq@@47ITe6wjUHQEV@Hs5T4dpaRm2QuPlYfMaMeRPcc4K1Oh3nX6@0E0Z8FpZ6uNRB0W/@L6vkAuElKbdIaR8DcixNfFdKdrPU6PzuwqINmiMcHlbyLimlV0mqcT0zOrcQd8A5/aW5@wgXaCYaoqPIa5IGGdlLo2p//0FWo9VpPVbj@GUNGpQ8DBCsQAGb8S17F8ktez61NrvJ5Rugd2@KxOhwj3vm9Be0ftWkTI9rX1gDC2dfn8R1emPzbG5tK9x1PzSxH1@a/oZ749UWmRjUwzm4/wBLkoPQr0RncP3whqbarStFSYG9NrNu7WZeaE2BAV8iL3nZ2B4hobbMbr2eDhXqnMdNPt4Pcl6Q79KO@057NDnQ@VQ4Q5laU5Fd036re008U4erg@pZNPptNBhQpMyc5Z1nalMEPdLi7/nEiaXWcqzsDgRNwoZl6dBZAmvQFopgvRVfXsKXCymbMs2vSm@31OaNh2n/yElBUK1baE2BsolrbRbV2K31B2xhpzNRi9cHPNodlaNW/DWRnQvgT7Yb15X6OG5pvcqTQXnRaEKdhes60dwQjNXd6WC@y1xWIivveuv1iXFgIimFtTttbWOa6hO0@wb/DPJZ9fBK6qZtfDmhYaYz8X5Xz7rO5utjywIpeEUiGW1oaPSMwcmWdco@kb7y7Hrf1YGmjj4W@U9Mc1WarJvtlYFGFogF2x8z00zh5Qlz7Ghi@UZo66JXZU@LiQTrqsksD@duJTIhwOja/JN5Osk5WzMAhfc8J7dzLh89KLEF9m0INpshHk1S0ClOjenrv9dCvDJtAXlOh7cPeK2UPlbOAz6HrV91Qq2202s3XN6ds/s8WWjgW1V5QB@9Pim/3WoA9bdXouRaAqvcA3Ts@/0@@9DTxSNXFA6TmcpTvu47Q03bnwQ3KnRBA/xuXP8zvC47EDDylrTM8fQLrmO5wxNhWyrgvZxrIe/V8lQf/b7Fx1EWtvVB4r4318U/p19y67heMMhfRrD/tilF0VVaLfiXXpTh69eQbIzZ9RV3ziDpiocVbG0hSbdl4uYpuW1erhLlHO22XWarZ51F9JN0/Bs6zzlj/pw63v1XZEyFlMeobPat4C8o6mK/FIJ@5/g53BVoYsBJN6sBYY1@sqyQTrakKkMjfOWywdE0cRKOCYcqo1822aJ9ruWXo8tbwY0tNwpGOHlMxNoWIW7WJaxUrOiJdIzMSyWa6zkUlLSUSFXzDQoPNrK8aW5pXChKpbJ8NcqhMK5JIxCC14@hNxieRANEFqhoVtwn@OvuXVNSxs5uzfuurcFJh@xb4OKhq@lInC3i2e94CY8h7l955IWndEW59lOvtB4NrRmhi0@qwpA76dw9xN8G6CNjc21Ey65tTMuFE7rK4ZjwacBHyjU8crRtb41dPmbKZ2V83RiIRT00hcnEznVpsu72aLI2maHz4@g6S7lceDQDC5oJ0oLZ/txeB3FPFfJuEiznS6Ie6XPZoH9sKsUmqUrk5YzRtCaKl88NbsGLtR@bHm40nMJvxAzL1vRdCfsr48N1/r6GHK2ig1xFzefoxyF9/yibQm8J0bXan06VxABkoLAYpko/8xVDHS6XRaXPcvF1VWBYc2QFbIcZ2Lkugb0KJaEXBzUDzawz2o93x@1NPSygXdnOMVtJFMyrRtztzwafxXfVZ3KVevO1iJxOR4Mx674LMeB1m@Fx6cH5@TuXloAXHkNQpf1jL63fAw7NBgL@ploLmfGVXr6N62@02XfLKQZqHOgnqHavoRxHkLD/QwXDY3sJZxIab/nnCgOgShc9rmvoWzNDFMs2/LWj/N4Hi4g8r@YGd6m4PaG1GN8qw8@FIJyupwij@/uBcz2LN7R8gPnnTjjUctEY3AQQbjDIFI19/yly6LVsM3LcP9t7bwONJSOPfaU0dhe2yrk17YKJTYp5ENswGJf33/yPB7mBlrqfZd@akK3cOz2pzPTytUEC0xm2aCirZaj86H9XsYjfmTKMa0zviPOLp7r0iJx/chZ1hN6Nh2Z3nt3pUD4jwePzBbOKd6Z9lPniWM70BoNQVAOjk2@GXhuFcjyiBjtMW53Bfq070zmhMCuaIS4tmEMzSaUb39mep@2iAN@ZHjGiqaIRg2pZxiY7uQVq980R1/ScGDIvKqzO4/Qp@aEeh2rGYbXQcVrtbiyjCN1c3Vkbi7HHTqOzd8kbdPw0Z6slyrQFNDr/WfRVVzFPzdisLTnNp/Vowu@hMRs893qq/I6MptOn7/XLFiyLb5gwBhZppt6jJufyS2fZQpoX@5aGbK9VobMOk2gyV4YLs3gL@@EzEBqkw9YH9QzRi0H58iEYc3SndCO5TvEdLAxgK8qaALhJyCxjNZYHJt2F1r9QXNAr5VdiVBpHptN3FLUpG3@njG5XZh8zEjscQ4t9wp2BvviCit1nsWeQT8lfnezNdfDmqeqNaQXSeqVE@m0kkexLbP1xsDxNIfoNRu1nvOHPKeeknHFKHaoGtH4csqgLbBLa9L8ujZQaPqm4vVGJii/3rqBb//8hSUzJeOBidPP8/MzK1VXx@1RZp3lM@2BcB2Zijj2C2RJcAQY1w@V3ZWaJ4KH/6OHX0tBI9zIZ/0zCUB03T23D8iPR7b4vA8HPnNcr2NNjgBv3JGwSpxgtnIQBT68ZqBpa1UmoPTscZ@PS3RDi7IGbeqOKXT0pKL0SVx7pmLaFwqdEDW5nSOH7xhL7eI5hp7ZVsQGaZyDUB77m8eCYOK7ZGo1LBtxJaiW4oSd5LNibegy4l76kgH0LcdThi59U0P32eHjo1N16GrLe/093KlxS4@b23GtF9KhwaovjVFoJpSvVWtbrpd6eKIpe48PVQywgt58rkOBD87ZzX1WjoiKUwONlLGyF4S@prdcQfz09MnjxGx/J4vt9UbOwIyHvfdOTpK46@VrJ0u9w7EPoHZ0nMnK6If7mhZfwr7PbZo3XCU9l6S0CtKpCb1RYMZP@YENdypXLWdotk@nQ/NzaDxRgrvvmXx@ZSafGhdWF2shK64kFFVUVlTz2Xho2TZ0ts1R8F1VnufWEKVliz4p/lm5UAU1h0xqlFmuPaxbC7CoxbC0WKPwYZG09G1u9SwFaka3h6aU4f59EdM0bRWdT4wOlCvLrSys@QDLZo77zsV7TDKbovOiBE6KB1ylWHcuMt9WBiC6U/jCgXvhCMbmygUy6wAEzvmlFf7StKeGrdAs1zr1ogSxcbnb2iDfNN9jqipY@3OBZ7kunf0L1tuzWIuM8TsSPh2FouztPTy8K8KxoOX6UJ88fc6eGW7L6N8RMIyx@R4YzzSjLxUct8KjsVZOtLZHAEpfC687XFqf@WaS47EdPoTQTYqt5nwPGN@V46r@SZGxmJFIxOPz5xCH9yDx3TcGnkRNG2cg7PU12xD7Y8Aj2DIkduXg2c7QJJu4l03yQdTY5pXYw1IqaTe4j0cuyUzsMQpO9@InVFU2Y3i2DqCKp7CzTX/zC6OTVdk1o2YZ5ICWS4NNTYV3I5bFriBWgiSfHT7bPzndPX1@UkvXb@S42PvG0TIMSMjfFflxpi1DbgQhoLXkR9XR7rk@JEenvmJz7vpZYpCphVxV5nI1y498H@NsXhlGKkWbwFLKDeCnyDw18oW6i04ctp9jorjYw1fie6f6RE15k4OWKU0ohRJLL0t4aLguZEv4L547Tb4sk0FfnrA4XQyYr@s4bZGia7K7Hz/Fg93Dx8@P95mP4IwNLq2216sUc/zwOawSignl1LFoPrnCoiJKFMqqUokeRIEwUTXKSrT1jg5@A86FYD51cNOeiL3FYpsEHygYDQol9V@@lbqJqrg0Kg5hoz5SUSYojwHYKW6n@bPfbfODUf3t8P7h6qMBqaK0WVkSW@VWbJRDilJVG64@Yp0OIqU9ccEJqLNj6yU6Ehe48hI1lMVTTuJ08AA/L18cQuMnRAziH6aIPWk8UAa6ARcWbojjOHTwfJd5VsZpOYabiFW2i@fHA88D6yMSgPrY9vgZCmKfdgT4SA1ERJJtErL8FF85FDC6swGs3DS7ls1cG9QT0yuxL4HPsLda4rsyFaUavRXFB80vDlB63qAfCnjrQBg3deal3v3a91LdMgPzJP0QbL8ibB0w/yo3v0xhWd8@NGaWfhgJE2sdx5onHtAc6R06Kt/mu19nxMKzbXzZx6wBFM0FURqD8xT4W7GZPIMTq30OBQUsBqUkdr3y9MxRPdbzvGEplUI2wpF/lVb6mRM@7a4Ck6dej/E0cMd2U/lcPqulAEnlwgdIxz92cUsRBxiPl4DxpQtrWHnVBPba2WEytnZmJV/mpZnaNF5m5FcBopsQVrrsIXI1BnEgyiwG@FVFNGggEloco6I8impRFEVtB1oO8scWBu22IITMYkAsTiMTzxOc4J0J3miKIyLjfhsPJrKd0NHAmwKQokHzQ6a4LImNmk8dD1hmbosq36iJy054K4WTtC6/E4QOMEceVG/Xptn@Iv8MYlG/VKz3HFQmvdjghctWfoEgThBESV7GsrWX7Mw7s@spzpsM2PTHgmXDzGyD@ZdT3RU8y/O9e/u4qtjiYVNILPbgxHZwkPEAMsNiekrPpLR8fJalbHZplkSORDKQHdx6fw3JgWgCMdEyrS@dobu7t3/4taNnJ7eOZKKQ0cVgIMmrO4kzRU3W6oEhGs7WfJE8PEidPHl44BfEDOl8SAKDPiJyoq3LyUxbR5CzdaGLWVuG4WLuVmP8gm8eW8Q3o69DjSLdwkNLf0C6tDZLOaAV1ouJ64Vl1Mrl1qE0g5cKgd7j22NuoRqLX93U6jvVMzsSvc0JSyrCy4i6hZUATGfu1mYKmf125jBjwd09p3jrgBuui5nldVHezOB5IrhBz3POZyepCIeQRyi/fjIgIiU15QddWfuOuB49O7lH53cL8ZNHwucthBDOp9dRPATq1L@mCKXI7NwxceRWz3B7fasp@edc8KO3/BOCglO3@BkVsbgkTqblCcfExUWT0kSl6dZYHKUdwUqydad4@fDiElRo1NeejaGL@MwZ8pMKaVj9kembjh0Qv4/GfH7OZF8bDyBchz7HJg1xgORWIDJQMhqgyvUnkBLiEK9JAo9Jg/RqeJSXyLg6aOdik7jaMydtqwuyPRZPgkT7WNPqLDjoCzNNB3vZUZnKbFYKa6viJ7jpKUz2DzrtbTJDwKgZqmW3zUksehmNl@qQPrpHL19cROPyMl6iU@fEMWztxePnAvS3tfWSxPBE7fTPdlsmLYrF21IC3BYB89NW/GPSi0W150p00UUFdfETb/QYjKBGxDoDY8hiY5ufSKMyssbOYnaSjvBQqvx4KpslEtRFgg95qIxidsjE2@@YYU9ZLFUBJkBX127j5401ZDVNVetgpkTibBOvL9gDjQtPd4hL0E@FKCUCW0EWgo4DYMQricoZHOKgv4SHbozoXJ8l3nSaOw0SOkgTyjWr3mOhCyjmNUe5WCyJAp2XikUG3HdbHKopAHtLzvm6PFBX7B4HmkGHVpUiM0F@W@JFKN0IR@RTse0c0ImEjpTzd6MzgDU78K3VG@Evtm9DXcEDNErPTw8ahXhKZsH29e7IauNIBR0HFwk6beKMaqimqbmg0TLvo32C0fBcogbfH4/H5hxQhZEXRGokTIbF69hmvKlpa7leRBSlACGz2ACINf4NHxwewOXPGS3xWy7sf/5zvPBNjm3ez2ca/YtENJcuw0sr51iOfbx5piibNT2XrjzYrBuGdyYzI5XdenRh9jrNw27qTJZZhmVTqS09//p8qOW3XtbU15O6XCtUkuf1Z@fs2bMv3jbexuXJxVQ@i7HtCNs7upY1yECktM2KDH9LH7qJaemzqosuRwEoi0TOzvAiN3lbTqVq0Tr8k@8reHi4WlWtqvfrb9/Ga9uQp8n0LIL3I7GjB/PwYroeP7EsK8XOhm67DT@nx@r8hr8IfxKJmMKEg1Ljbmww6ZDbZNfsdsf7xpS7W5Exfg48EffJN1@8eIGGF/SwN8ciPofO/DRKDSMXYXpa/7Ofbtwkr541dv7s24OUuYGfI/x87@YJmk@03McbGx8/fJjNJoFK3Pzsm8@@sbu7m32UzD2r5e5nlfTGzp/@ycaGru/oqY2662r1aO38/AtZT2dl9c9@Em08e/Z118ViwSfDNDDiuwA/DXWqc/YGnvMOw38yv2mHzAaam503TI@8iQBbR6b014gwXgsrpCWFnw2mVe9v/9cfHL2OeJGqnnoxgq8XeR3JFyLcCAawZXzbRaQa2cFg@ZvINFWpVMC4/V//HcSvfg3goM90B17VnA8rP41UlQpFuY5U82DQdB3S/b@/9a2VAz4PavDI2W1dvl@HZ4ueHQlPC1LSqdRCaK1wT7vHmO31PNPBj8U/NnyYUbahu31cSyQSdVWBR21QpJSm6Wc0UhPmKRpoiQTOZcZdWMhtxiDCBfxeRIiZgJuIobhZOBCPcYcXi@FeLHnKL/5xnmMpkt94YD6qVkHy6VV9q5qgZ@OsVCKaN1JsuyA7zgMcwIqeyVH2ij0WJK7K6YIuJ5PJBw28LZNNkJLKJDIjG@OUYZE5ekbYzMbCThHmR2OzMB8abh@fP//f//yHf/4D@vsh/f4jHqdkt61OaqsW24rXLxpV/rBqVa6O5Kszsjxg6VKhVEiRL8il@jHT0p9cR3OZ6Am2Cf7jD2hGgqdaxZePBtqqEe5S5aaZm/CpBhYKMYuyPBwTgsgnagRaXLG2RKld1FnVz9Cyp/YAiknWt4tyvarn9CMoOk2mgiuy3qbLnIifI3Yfng34o/@NDZQHgQu@N/Ch930edMmzEWBz97OIqhSpRWops46NRBDowUZpo1DKl/RUg60GVF4FPXIRliPqtlpQdZAcCqttHHOGr7OE/5wl7nyeq2pDGMng4E9RnElEivwjPFWJRa7gqb/dqr3davhJ10RlTewo9WpCYAQftfGgnlBubmrqy0S5LP53qoGxTE@izNAIOanfKMrOSwBWmwcbzTrRvPMAoXPg9FYbL3cAfGKntlNx9uinUnVR6i@rtZ15EAK5Bw8SKGYfAIDqZp3FE4lNRdmorcwDAKzHGPQEoABvdm6qN7Wdm5udHfjfofeN@ILrzc6tf/rMnhVhZv51ZLSzWqp6ljoTbFMHu5qqoouaOgNDFb4QDlogKfIWmhX2hD/siW3DP/yEA3xtfNBkkye3k@GJH0g4cxcpssWYWdK29EwqN/k4vw8KVa2uYL@notS0fK5OKo0UuUYNAGpsUYqksJ9Q5N2FIrkUQfNLbbGtyJBp25nIFogHl21wfykC@QQAV1S/Xr376n/F39m7r36fNV/j3@M3@Pfaw7/TFv4dv8Y/dvoG/449/HvSxL9nLv6dvsa/3Sb@nQ7w7@Fr/Hvi4d/zLv5JkQposZv30/30RVo7187BYLH0iKV76Z7WRjGaNll6mp6y9MDR2mAy4S8NJivdYekuS9tpW9PAEwweS3to6sCnC38dgDKCPyudRuDpCwap9FE4060C9L2GZj1@JtVY9JUJ2qaqqWk1bzXqeF4zqKHlSOrsLMU71EzPlvHY5pubRmP/6aNGI0XzMmdPnKPZ/9HRIGxd@z84cp4cOQMH/o@Ojp6cgYZSTTxIKA/gqVQTO@JzP1It3z8rKcj6fi2LpHbun1UzCprzCag4OrolPvCZQYRvdeNMirJLaPIvy6ROlC8vypdlMgTWF@UGmP0AIhg3gGNZqCHgAvHOXqRIg7iE54Lgkg2Nl@Dpm7gh9eLyDDVq6CoF/0CPsPUf4N/6/9b/k@csVqvHodtydbMToyeOf/H41c3VjXhX47GYsMR24A8dwI5Rrm6qaKRAV2CqxeL1@M0Nd4N3LL7DAVYxjZ0qRZ4FhLoeCdKkdPkr9g/7xbTFc4ZHCYfmuM/OJul0vNz0jy7F@R3jmqYa42W6UmKzWdPqf/oTOqD2fpwC5bLlsrbFuEXP6uVy1rdtF8rlgm/ZjMWKt59q@r6WBzUhm43Hy2Ww3PfBpsEagC0AWN@SA6ima7So9pcjccwElwixNB3qjCf9R@WSfO9eTNwOdn83fu@eXkxfXwcuwyE4aXNOjUbbGjUa6J65vpYbMk0zF3NgTxeur0E@RePOKPYUL4iAhGKKxj7Wq5Rm0RlB3rfBm2kpfYZFz3ANzxvF3ljDpIzLIF05Tue3p9PO6Cz6s@9/@9tn0UpFVmRyzWoIAFNhuZ2dfLZazWfBnC8AceTNK36VQTdR1OI3mymZE4DJm9GI8NIK23EuFKPozyI77H4V6rSLD7u6iVBJs2wuHmtOzfgVuPhuWrHIHVk2HyskiuKvshFnVWik@B926DKJ7Nb21gPs0U1WPCiIy1dmRbupXJklHBC7KbfEtTu4@ci8dy9TBIIW0uUzqdF4tHu622hUZGgPZbzjg6EjiXQJbwQZjqI1GjPKFes1zFz9LBotlR8QM2iFHItEyyKcEoW2gRWKRAPJ6uDOQsg4wqSLbxm/KH72efZ4d2//NKnvQIOtH@zuJfWT5w8jGlpzMzt5Z9B@vL/76Og5RHj2eH/3ZP@Tw8/3nz8Dd5ddzh5ftor37Bs2LbFfshfSl6M3hmka5tg0G5fj8eVr9qVlNSwgYX9sWZbTHTHXbJimOYRg/lOGX8tyjS@/NEZDeti7H3/33Y//23e//f13v/3dd7/9w5999cPvwu934fd9/v3@vy3m8P2zr/6n33n3W78Njv8Rfn8Ev5/@7Kvf@Bb/kf2P4fefQ25/LH6hcPwnAaxf@dlXP/jJz7761R/B71@J349u/37tp8t/P/zO6h/G@8HvrA/z/X8Hv9/jsPyw3/8t7obfW@F/i4f71R@9@/V/z///VPyh8bff/fof40tY/tmP/vQ/v/v2f9D1wp/@m3ff/f677/zg3Xe@/e4733v3nX@qv/uNf6Olw6/feffDP/irP/y9v/rD/5H@f5fev/c@/@9@9M/@4n/7i//jL/5Q/H4Kv38Ppp/@xX8Anv3bP/gx/v/gD/72j36M///Lv/7bP/gXf/sr/zMZfpMb/p9/9W/5@69/7T/9zb/83l/99Ft/8y9@@je/@Qd/9X/@6v/1G//pr/@73//r/@Hb6PibP/2rP/qVv/z2d//yO//8L7/91Yr3d9e@v3oP96/@EVzeH8/3gfM@@fpQl69@IXz@PtSYpQJ8Agz@y@9@45eAx3@d2/57sMF/4PW9wDLnwy3fm1kAwr9cEumXf/bVP/9JYPulIGDELM03GAW9kNgCRXqrWKRhQN9v5zYUSO57WCnnUvgeVud3P/7Wu5/803c//s13P/4VFNxKtpjcTSra@iVnIPOV3HuEw4D59wnHeCvyxRfwmiRo@ExJoI19IQJ88cUX0uQ6Bd2Z9INrcP2CnPjDuBf4MeHl@wl3XKwYDsONad@4ic7X4aTBrIkh4A1Jpy@@JC2B38QGmADfLSmXARuhjj5bfm4SUk7zPSICFvec0FD/BP6lbJFFINJkkphA/wcMiQlLgNfDBKtUKhS5MqGgYMU4E1YtQPAJjtBUEDpE4nGSjQKCmDwkKBCzkjhmja3KhEdMILwqQSDk0OlY1nQ5Uag8ggQrk0cMYSFwAvvqVaVaqEyqCO4toQAJJR4STgiskphU34K9QjAhnhR59BZQKVQSiWoBE8RMclolG5SmlqPMUd4TjPKN7ozWYN5/wNjHslYQCyU3kGA8NL4Ts9D3aSLkPvifJbZEdujfN9Jviwi@QUmJVHixYGIbPL4IAHAVRVVVBj9FQWwegPeEg0pQsvBJJESxAjx8fJDgAAWMZZGg8k2QBdKPVLY@@ElU2Qc8fByzkJcbCW2qg0Yq57dxIPOf3Hr@m3@y7Fnuio/Eabq5uSlFqnJGPqI5gQR0U0fnJX6E/zXvGJSYnC/K6GzSImFOY3PzGXW1tx5twVuD//0NWrubYGUizmYUR3SijOeafZzgvwcPttjHUAb0nblJTElknCwOzCK5dxIJWYdUq05CegnSToJKRICuJXVSoZmIhJRMMqZWIujHjo6OBGrk8LIiJaAO6hkN7TiIPB6PIxBDVZMq0JR/VfqSgyoMKvmKr7qJJU/XgjFdz5ZBwS8zdGJhfVyDjho6vn37FliG5u9Lh9CfYmIqX88WyBMc@F6ufn/qLxrXs0WJ9x@ZludXYcboNq04i0ssxrbiEl/pyZEIZgajeqEQRVMcykSNbfkrO/KadFrSUSxJ@6U0sm3i8NHx4UmJcbQEkWIBpHiZxt0ENkWNWL1lohLsP2Xpidt96Eygg5iU5aSWxwnTOI23MekbTqlUeatltyX4kn3M8FAWvoMLqh6uwlV3dhjRrXql0BgkGoFuealaFaszmCZVT/ZPIcLpEdP0tMqg@3iV3dazuWxOz@TzuW1dy@aL2XyukAFRn0/ndF0rZrPFQnH7hrFXKisp/AI3rZCPqzj70XA6DTypSWWvpOoXbKJiZpQbqdqv9E276/U2cdGEfJaWQ0TYrKWT@KdnMvCGJJNabru@sdG/UjAHZ1QcV7j6BVKVrhTgdvYRPEz6SGIfgRM8kAYuaWFiPdHhUVks6sDN1DG@skPWclCp4tIZIMrBScPwU56zDYGHr66uQj8psvHNb3qsWoWunnJ4IEVAYPWYv8pBsdpqT6VbqttjvJ0efLuMta3PLbxIQfWvlNczaVWK3NzcdADS4QHOiZGVx2jj@6ZFLk0w30wM6f9//oGfHX7gSBWXrjtGuxLc6w7VNH7VrrSdFl2wUu5UanW6L6fcVptOe6q63hSYWxRlJdrsO63zqO9p4V10uB@rkjJSaqMBvOA5jUalEk2lovf17VxpIzVKqXS@Eot1oEbf1/Pb4Hhmc9dYB1xy6PJy3qlYaqs@Uk@AcSGeXtLzuZsdcepYFfKEqFURkSuBX8l2bPMGF52XjA5IwasWX1lUkvVcQS7XyjP7dl4u128eDMy2ZbCzNC40vloaMZ@Xb/xwkLQJVY72scQGeMsHblcopc/S8RWR0xAZUCZMpR1x0EmVVsrUQLLU8criWn3HPwKlKjFJ1xU9o2Q0Rcvg/x0GHf/fP7wO/zq@IVZGl07xeJunUNwgQW32GM9i9Rx26jh07c5Ds7UixF7PoCVBeyPHdf8eYR4a9jn3emTxszcCr08NPG/bHVheb0WI58MB7qwyR/9oEPYHTUAQeZAHeAivUd9xlgXYZs@frcjlk@C0KyAGP@4Kgh8ffvLpaeh7ur@796mUZw@Pnj5a@OREoBx7vH9wGli3ua8fNReA@Mb@48eLVvGJYFuLY3EbLLftGzQJ1xTeg27EPWHM5WfGNBpf8O0ulhusceP7mkrSqb8HhuqH1TRZi292m0gTvuFaKBbadlGShsx2Ltl2mrWdft/AK8c6G@DYM3Btv4ltep9uxsOkL51Rvw1VzNyQnuA2gqKG9yohEtKnAGQwbtHuRsuT8PiONl4GhgO/TbyZeIwX7q1whA86oXFkdXse8y4dP4DUNAwGvw99IL4Zfrz1Dh5Pg9xu@fRvB5cikuEZkUIZGNa7KbftsXbvnnbv2QgYvFpIl0pn6RvgsMrD89LQnHiuOXT3J8Us8Bsbs@dQA4xRS5b1EkrLRAr7pmzzr//l74JCyHKynNe2Dlg2yRpqI2JsYTF0rWoKmoJjVsDxTAk5disFwimiyTKuZdzQJJW0Ob1YyBWKGb2QLBQL2ZyWz@WSmp4EfXW7CKpNWito@UKuqCUL2WImC6oU@OaK21KErxxJbRFI@JYArN3Ci3928AYlR@1VpQgf92dvYkacRYzAPmayCXFkvLQVmhbcLLVlVWQ9y6B/Duo4QDRYi0UODvbSBwey/BAtOIO5l5blNlpyhXR6@6Esm@SzB@qeLssOj1PAXdKyxy3p9MM9WR5zAHjAmCz30LKfx16/LFto2ds9OMB0OmjRMT4EO@c@3NL3LdsQzEZLJkPDBrL8OgAH4XZ5QlnCdB8tmCb6HHCfPfCT5U98fNJpgHDMw3EIn/p53d2V5UNu2d1Fnz3KeI6j@hladumR5RFYoDbIchcMXWzjZLkJRqwTstwCU2tqgBtes4SnUNmeIctTTiAkkSxPKLTROpflhu@OyXz66adGz2ubXf5MR/wLvHgIPtZkvH/Q/OSTZrfbHE139z85Rp@9vU@NznQ8anabIlqzAY8DccDnfDBdfADHw0bD6C/1@Qx87AWfxrRhIm4N4zXgJJ4uJjJo7IHPHvgsmzXh0OAZQNAmPg8H8H1oNMnHf8iHvpNmUy4jo@JGcrorEeoMXVuYHBitkVNG@6SywVg0Fk1Oa/l0vUwebAB6Wbp8Q5ckxuiWaew@ggZ1Na1NKul6ZVLZ1vk0eycmn030nCUnNwb3tSIoXcZ9Tc8mJiXcNOl0oiyqaPdj2r2tN7GnoFxlsiX57P59Ra5p9fu6Vijlt19ujWU5XsL3/cx26Q10w6LQs8NXvLZdvw@a3CzK9nbCSOml7e14@QbI4UGb2Rx7ZqMRi12axnk8juhiZwSywK9onFI@rXInNklOKhwrNo2XJxWtzA9IYelbsNp4Gte45TkjDrEL4Cb30yW6BFLWigUZ0k@lYvE4SCYSIvCdLUF58fXT89PTL0BmQT9QdJKe8ZvFysL6yad7KvSbhA1P0VIPUDF2RuoeCpY5H37Ik@90CkJW/RQaPlBSfTdcxj5y@ur@BPq2qF37Hv7ZKKo40UI9/XQOzgn0EHnKuAuwTNvF7ZbJ8JAxq82MShVMRpvFCCtmxC@pyW1Uq5VGZcDvcawGsT7jV1rPwBy6HPdgbyJFv8Kl3cKjUUnfzMI/HQ/YQx6I7qX1ozUqD6ENT5dtPFzTROsmm0QmUrWN5489rDy8GpdwUOKmbFZMvO9SjuDO4ft2ZWy7Rsd8Zo5wK@7h0SbrMPNVCxeFvzqjmzH3UP2@UaojZs/hETOUajM@7xSyIuFiXwfFg1PkivYn4DTlDXRkYi/j5ddgG22yWFt9GL@fLQMJH7IGi4Nb@lXnVYfpLJ8t03VBLIbAoJYR8ejSyXil@hnA5qDPSyXARTDBOYDFtDahG2C1yceID62bcrdSw9DX@NpRZLmuKLXrulQtS1WotOVpxKi44yadT8nSTU1P58sTcNO2s@Uea1aaLyflUWUInWlW7kO5ixEEvu/CKAP1gE4A5801i737pW/Fd5RchTuWCdh1H/QGaMQrk1khZSo1PZtP6vksDjjkM/DTknpGx@XTST1dTOoatNPQfkN8@G2DPQs/CAPNuK7hsESsH5MZk5PpSVrVkpqpJSHf6VdW@1U8eR4D5YNoFk96zj7etQkOyELAtmSFrxFP6Fv9WNthxo5CTAxypEz5NJI9NrTghXCOTaPPw8cVltmK9TdjGGjzdDzcr9VLpf3J8OvgFVNe388nttOJN/F4OQbCM15xzddEZRQ7RIXhBjC1GG1h7nhQS29Avq@UhnIDxe1tatt6qTberCkaZDB93d2Rq3IdiuuGCS0HpQlXdGaqysytgUo0XlrLtKJellSazabUtJheXLV6Py7hGdICoDQUkhCJy2Jnsr8NKRaNbuvRaDxaxrHQDVmMn4H44/ffghyO3tPuy6BcySW5qGOAmRSlnSbpsH51I2H3mGWLUuRKurm62QmPDn/GplMjofjWe4x1E5sSS9FKJ1AH2QaZFLVK4@W7ld3u8a643prt7kmREmOhdeISOxMnIaQ2GPvQ5VWJnepL/j3DNYyQqkSn39RYnVZAmBZ2rNjnuCfvPotCtozRoKbrmXpN34amE8SxH1TXtfJmIsUiuEhSrUK5uVcS0YRF@Kp3PVj1zkITXrSqL7WTqKbOJFkmCSbWrsQKORyQNCHDbyNcZuxd@QMpJTxkPWaUuICo1eNvn1r9q0JG4X19EFo3N1Qm/vriz17pOSgl2/EdoMPjQWMALVsuh2N2kdSroftNvZB5cnhkPxodmP44fbYhVyMsrSm4crdcEq45PnovFwu6rJ8nI@xBpBxh50pUK9GaZDY8Kb7cfll4@eT50fOjAylytnG94eAgLvNLk721v/Z1CBjNZKOMnVUik0q2LFatVKuKtqOz@9AAMLzGuKPllfR1lTNwlTzyOvi8@6UfZSc7BbDroNyWoBhyCb1a1bZ0Fo8M3331@7hB/Gr/893HLOoaU/Z3f/ITffvv/uRf03KQ6E3ZpfHC7QiERKOW345cXQ2vrm7g4X65SD3Ckcpux8HMVx9pkRlTl1KGsbWdyOoP7HJKhNW2tXjEVSJiGHw7F3GvhZeeLoDX3hG3yfmcHI/sH1s5XXuwg3yiLeMT0y1GpEjhyatrxsDSqra7XUsnUyrFSm8VtvNW2WFvcSj6rbLBXlWqODGp4Z4Kfzh1q1qtIhQWrSZSW1Gm58CvdlOuJxgNx0K/76W5ZW@dzQuRsw1WLNrgbrpbrnDacqHXtmXTn7nlumD1bebWly6TcZQ/lWq3aVpsx2S5KpT8VgrQOYu/@6Xf0PX83/3Jr103rhtfQLNQLBbzmh75ufbzn0OANbt4/f4YjTzjdls0BP04tuKyTbUFXUi8gbXDeHi/V4f9OAa6gtW1oWuONukCFSAqmQY/GqYdo2BbuMkvSeo0HdwQL0tSoHaSujzqtpIEg23hccdQJaUr6SP0glaVVUBUSh/NQDG8KL3fd1oNtz8eDWlIP0bxtHqS3YMokMJHeI7OhrjPnOStopVxgfCtqBxll6hGqhAbmK6Lp/JACyJ9BFEeA8PTHUpsaOA@Wgxp2SDgVQxCeJJHuwZp1yHtPo/QINcY5Z4HSDKOHY9kg0otfQRKAVHBAmWBWTsQoAwi5SMgAOQhJgBbdbbDMnF2ZSUS5dmRPze4jJRfYy421kkYDaHhJfdB5DKGAydQ5fGaBOQLUcKgmYUcfSAcBp/1q0BnAKOTDZUt2mT73qAAFh1oEaOssXv3ZlhVKlY7zihHCP/cGuIAFJWDvRxXAOZ3oz5ul@QksxMJLOyP5tkOKJ4gdIHrFH6KUjkUlclovZEk@H9vpkWOXCgq8ihjBkR58VrRApJBZCQ7L8MW26kwTd@OswD5FuDeIqTouJ@gb3g2@VjVv/A9bwDDn0f8o0YlvLg8NKgn@HZxEyeD1m6M5zziUR5cGIjNl/ywDpRih54fO4gFWbH6FJpfeE@zjv7JP7GMFsdos5OSCA9aJapnGS7XzMXxQ7EwNIOvgWfciHQ2aCS@5UCBukPHpkNxaAM/Ln4FjgAZJc4W4WiP7Us8F1iUDUUOY@TSuSLI@YgxHfJDVy1RXJxvbI6ge@vTJsnMrspagzbTiyxGjEZnoNgBuDhFIoSbJh5HNXKafXMAKJ2YJsNzYdxSKtUFnWbcpINgnljAV70DC5oS202JW61Sl9a5lTrFcw0VpwPas9hWG0E1CKsfn9oUh670Heec9a1zk4/VxuY2JbtMzydBYU0CZWc/IGwJh4X1TJKlwTvJQ8FvGz7b3FhIhuJuxKbx29@MthFrYIleU5tkjfDGqgvDDtGXnmtJ9H3dqesfa0Cb88GuBiLXFBuaK1HcSxns1JfEAQ0VOhtAxfH6YQy0NP9gAzSCHm5eQAhFk7CNAaHZ8rcIYy2G3H5EDQDVPahZeMaRNyrhxnbAZNSOtaDqCQFvs49ZRpfophA6dUKcEAEwsOgr89DBD6JiPlyvDQWj8slikCtQOwdt8MOdlYL9ML7P3Wim86dm7M02BDhsdCitCuPVwrfkQhasHcjPlPUN8MwDhksw2YjJCQCbkOMyBx3EX4zOuV0iWVJityElGUIQpAYopCr4V9qx0AG@Eng8NFx@@p04Deny8lKlY7nGI0s1XTzU1sV7@lLDrgXasJPyzMFQXB9i4YVSAu7MpPCzrPH2xvsTujexeG/Kv5LUcStid3ss2nGj2Dhe4Jmt3QEd54HnaLjEUAcWnffcitEstiv4T68nr3z@KyH/KYXoDQJhDMFMktNkKwnAks3WebJz2S4LjwuqkAAcStH0HfEUvJFvGbi@yRp2ghCOR@vOfXuzf95y@g7qJDIfU50lzXPoh5z6VmEfWhOIZJuXbHc0MqYx8o9jaGTg2JTUHjaFZp98wAjNDLvi57JZk9q0Phd9EkSHRi2YMh7hWR3S1Xqg/JA@9J9w/wn4T7j/ZJaon2xtUucqGTrdYHaQ6/GIJz8kgpn6YW74gXYzH4IMijXTOAgMOZ1zu4Ffq0KxfXpzG5RjxWcM4IkhENyMpWovz2pndds1L7fqiVQXmF0mQkCJA@hanWh62Q7MSP3@RX/ouHNONp7sBa2SwBudWj3BDZxXMI9BARFjcHpZeBhTd6DyISCuEIgMAwTUw8ATVYNdL2bFy8Exj@QJjFOTZzTmiNUEMnXSvoSXcAN1iZOeEzYMqB4ChO5BlgBN8GF@zeFHmPvS4cUI73D1wyp06vIADwWJ1qNAyYWqwmVNmQophJWi@GgC2VFdrSxmxfeHoqgteIWyeSPKP4z@xgej34F6sRx7YljeYJSlcFUxJyao1aaoLkRVVq2EyhUwSG0ZfXMELdc@109Faw3JbKX8bgZPB7PgXuKNbbFQ4bfivHxo849sy6WAFaaVCmRxWuHVktcLn6Sc4EE0V0Sb@owg4nMBAjDSS6OZItokHG1SqXDBwSYrol2GkJwQkhMehYeerECyLqJB7ym46hOLp4530oOmJQM8jTejoAYNZYbXtuG09Jd4YBFOX4o0ZzKHuEDwEKrYyGet@tLUayGkQ0JrAQAy4i0AbX4bSklaFHiaEtgCGcVJ6csobhNswGUFMBiJ4DI/1C8WMBn1gUHhlxPUDkDdlRM1SdZwiRn9pflPTvqO/k@77ZieD6nNO6aTC3//KI51pGyogoa0Dy2dRYGMPZnn4oLbOZ0jgheH9RzQ6pqXDostUbbBPeXfjZtq9p1mamDgUhC8IyG4MTfu9x9wHoQ9GDqe4TnZbIl3mixiu2Xp8z6D1bUd6JqED/MEXa/tmK4d9aBQW07XtlwziXf0cpXdpIUJ/JRgKawnC6PjSpIYeuTdWATN@QpV3UYDb21qNGKu2e/ES8GRvGhVkT2jUQn7v2AKxQfxJIAeDWMO3j7uxe@GiefOiminVus8djQUnlFIZJeBDGuB/g@@PdBgmOvMeo50Aiaq0k0vRmcu95yB0wWtb@yqEsZeAH84g40IGcMh4ZJkBnZpS6GDh6mWxFpJIy6ifvbBUdlnesyIB/H1eQBzxEiy0SKNkbKjJck1VibHo/npnXw4vidhfE/W40u98EWcede8wj0/LOlMbAYBAs7QyNyNBmYd5Fb7FjpzqATOqFfxCO@NYpuWWrUR010IuiuCqx3gj2Rgc8EWIP75KvqvL0A/@v77Fp@BV9mdTEHeDHAFYIxOCXf9ec0YBD@Mo@y5nVzA2o/eMy0IixcRHKAKAWosCS4bD@@DijmEbrcbHCntA76D53HF1C2@p2VUFe65BKfRRZKd66uL6FGjbfaNqdmOiZDJEFw/x8fQYSN59X4ZR0FHQs/hfb0YtF3xwBeacSQ6D1RawTJG8iIeX81WPIgVcA@NlBOGh6vph/63RDMO8VX4aDX0A6JRPEjKvrBw@HM4HU75@bB9OsTal6O8/eElifud7yYI0EEsXk/Oko2vE5/HsSBL79EiBGHV@Szj8Y0@RDwZ8XYZfhiJ7s4pFG4oUsUvZWn@rPPlJW6tK/EQV/g8yaeN3o8l72K69@a5EKtxYDMRtvdhTcgtyLgUo9WKhSFyl7Ul5ti3ZAK60TidvaJVaSwRqEFMknSeRd1t0i/iEvaMD@GLA06fwxcBdk2vwRnKzxuOaYlbFxj5DIxhSGsRLqCkA5QQFTnJBRqhUJJvhuBXN0GarZVptm6l2ZpLM6gB80mGAkmtuSRFKWDxrCuCvtnxVkhn9MK@M3zWiW14bMcY4WjFVdSKlqwki15ESyCQo2a0tB8DoRxtR0uPyOBGSydkOI@WPgPDrG5Fr6Mlv1pggBFYyfAA3YUIR3srWtqLxW8kzzg3XT9dNVoKyhTC3OdWogiQAvMNWiNOsdmOyKY3MqFhI6UyyZBj3CR2n2gcJkm/NPzz2wvoFHT0xDHOLQrMEkybazRCLQZPB5oN/5TdJTW5JFrz/aMDWsoUBMFkEtDHC8ch8KCGR6Lzwogjhr40owFfQBDlZmk5RizUkr0nOiJ14FAq5Pn0iXoq6QPtGPnXIHB9lghdWSHi@@U1D4IX4PvhiZFX4XkLHT85wgjnZONL0EKivoquyRSW9TwuovTDJURj3fOB8C5IPwgvJQIbkumgw9HkHCY2dIbzTEK@uAjeCsehQTleKZF7F6KRVBA1c4U3OYucoWAIV/74uuyE4iFqcyIIPWvpOq9lQbtAshi9ZrIupKnyygcohGQO1HCzdU7XgTwSRgrHxU2S2opVzZAflydJkmteTEJkFQ9uGRseTz3ovO7jcS4f1n31Y05wrCWGAEIxg1S4fHU@QH93uP7uK9Q@ERYSWKZYL29Kb6vXa1vZBcz7s2RvFyB6Jtmj@FLlKEhhRnLoHYQ083W8dkvFxyUfXMnniQbQF7R9n2xBn@AOui32LTgs1BJGF/OO5zo4nuurCXVbI@lfqL7SomJKAg7PeIDpLGvrceUZX1bE6EPj20b/gwt4NF/A4cJDeJSB0QLJeS0fjW1a5TKr2yC2uQuKVK3EuCCn6dKgmGeOIO5p6jaYtgWHo8bxo6Onj78Bje729nZctNHTGX5Ya3GsNWjHOWRaNR20B0u6LXoST/jHyW4cjqd7VzfObPmWLOHCGpQBA1Lx2U/U8biQZSF5vlB3IR4PG6KogHU@qwbGnFRCVcfAJtsSdPWAIKYX2zIEEF@9BXonqbcWp7PsGw28a7PRoOar0cDFS42GaMWwaPwZ8fjPIxupsTuiazz5RQyXEj8uiT06Yi8@3T1lp5/us4Pne5@xbxw9Zy92n57iJudnzx8@Ptxj8Nt/erLPZiMK@OClNdihBLo@Mlsm3haGp15l@UFMe85wyuVObC/O3U@MAfvUaZk4TbXjGoMHPW5RbdOr8lj70B2d4himRRcTDSwP11vQrTrQjUXlpk2b7HCRP4OwTejTDrDPO3DaVseCsBL2fYeW6fp7vVjfghIEeevvB01yJQkv0KGlQ3TVFa7AuoToBoTHuRsAY/D1V3SdqeXyCGZbFedMzZ4PpuDp/vGTE7b79BHbO3r66PD08OjpCTs4Ogbrs28cPv0E6Hl4cnp8@PA5elHAJ0ePDg8O93bJgSOQVhluZP9y7HprUVAxOFGldY4z33RrbWCbH/VGDZ5dGrTd0GXRsY3SxzL61huzHS1LYxfVF9ziSFMFLLa5e/zJ59DmM/M1znD6U8G0/kB@7tJFTptptkOpQWWpQn0ri@oKzZ6ixWk@YjBleK67WaYt6TEyJ5kPnBbxtC2TyXu4RgXHvvnOdarLPmhIaANgIyh/wUqF0X0M0Whyh0BWIbVW38FD7nhqfBGhsGDUB/5Sk7JEFBNrZRAoblI4tHE8SCsHDsD34KCLZL0RD8AygQMPwLLcAVXRQ1w7wnIixNg7GqN4Znnu8OVgeEDTwmw7cHhoUC@2IHDi5UZFarDgPhvcx9@nWzf4KA/dBma4LcuiKC6Fxxsp@n1eMUx@FxLIRD6VSGvbIKQMwqaDUw1i2Ru/BhB9gRtwnZDR8VwWq8RVdoqLg0zb4veddPuGzZdAzZbuEO@xAp7TUhELbK3gnpA2v3aeGBDvKJrHI4j3SGiF5vvGg5gPb6VoiDWSdFeXvwTtLgQe3kLgFwEDgJS5nk6LWiraVYpgnI5g5ZjrAEfiuO3bcHhg5/a4Zc5FEKu2Yl9ab97EBZGTc/0kf50iYQdF9MYcgVpJU5kdZwR1nMQq3ayAUrDVc4aexcswNp8DmnGiZg5CY8MGqb2qVOdSQzospmg7dijRJnDxilSbwJTvkypxPJ87D8TX7Jo94HxohPm6O0THaOKtrbO5syROIl2aOPwCijDNlePg59QjTLj@Kc1kx1uGN3UVKtVHD8@Ut6@SeF0XFwv8hjx/0SH@gDExLageNM9HCxZHqHeJmuZfs@KOmxhbrMET0hJruQ8M@oE9C/p1DxrlwI8vN77tjntjFt3J8fq6wmMpKJnEpYluLzaTbklW85NMUpw6E0tAQrITkAVZH/NdkgQzkNcPcBcMlkIZKGKjHMF@@8IlJkKE@LlrjjsgWcRdcqK4A/hxVqUVFbOrNXFXS7g8Ui9jDyuJajw1W1DCQuSM@SI66UPW4vHQshRqr26Be7QeHMjv9wdXWIsdbx4@CNqjtdA@CDclsRoWb5ZCsN4f7Ns1YHnj9guBhbwnVwPmjeRtaAGnB8yZ3IwEq2nXp/jqVtlR3QMw2PbiCEoANJTa2KYpav982RiPEA@DmSlEJ6eP9o@Pmcz7JxAX5B52GdpCDCLsDfZsttrWsknYqYHSFHSWA@XJd5lb0eY/6yrzUuKtEBVCB0kKegTCYnaJbMeacKknWhZSIWj1PQlEn3Lz2F35MsitCcA30AcEZGeFFsqgtDSbEd74WG54EbigW5LrxuE1/LTCmrfdeEPbaBoGFF4TZHRxZ8ny8nvB9eOSnw5XsMzXY8pwGzRpaG@gn3CCt7RDQFWdL8E1xeIXKS6y5wp2xKcdLvxKz2vYf3@GIkbiSjjXhUNiXSjHAjWuH2/6ag4tSMRmwMCVnsKTr2gGD1/Ek8tOuEDjs0YvNt8EgZKJd3Y9CHMFRK/flIMLpGOzdrISKOThurZJ2NR8LOs4Oitgl1cH@hjXQucXxcNiUiBt1yal/MMkxVuJuZR8mi/NjO8JkPO5XOYu2Iu58KMrf1/YvA1ZlJ/eYAj9@xlId@rS8D5w7uHTpO8/Y4A1pONL6/0KsxARVJ0lbcpc3qkxCuMHuPBxIUAGD3zGa9AWU42zyQJuy6HzFikMnYLcykOoCgcZ5bXmFvVv1ieHAvnO9DY@PD1e2TAQLh28wVX5T5yRa8525YWOVwk54bbVeTdzNLIpGN/PNEAoMdrGtHazHe224wteea7Qk@bbwjnpiN1JfNlt0h9roERoeFHFmw9xdK@8OLynaOVwVg8OH@@zLTr5rjM3FimP5HhI9mxY9joESAbTuAQ2H7SH72O3BD/AIemDBDLRbr4Y0SZ@J25EEdCaa3R/hlgWKmSrtlj6Hbdl2HjWR1L@2GVy8h5EpFHY/aOD@LKR9XR5Lj4g5w7tGMRKyooqU1RwwwFdhDQPgpcmuocaLNyp4a@UXHNftZHSCul8UaLc2UkvOagV68mtVkVm0Pga9sAdjy7b512nd9FhfTb8sjlpTd@8ZiyXZRlIS7/HzzzV8pUUnRO5De8CK6aJcwWC9@n2sDOZMZXOKMWJZTbrh5c3WJwM1Gku4Q6JBS5lWwOfC3GLnVcZ1PL1il1Jlwc1u17GTX5eouIltEQMHe5BKwoyhs/M17w6tqnhUVfTvqD77unOK7E1hNHWEHB5Yows5/Hu00/mRuNQAcAhMLHWmwbU@a2HH@FqNtx7otrmZUwMkyUZcqyECpL0Ee0K0nDDOo0n43BM2wLMoFSSoM26E3pP49JHaXU89BzyEQkpyFrs2rqWPvK3MaVpRAGC1Ky6j84OwZmFieHEEHed8lXUisbVNQ33TsZDIGoYk8ShfCbLuKcQERV7uWp1yVVNo9VDJPCaz2uKxnZ26NJPYDVXpVE8XMphjGjDRLqORpwAgc@QZhswCdLcXdr2IUH20a6hgbvQGJVH@2RogbxEmiL64PJvdkX7myj@DhCAE/4jrnOpYohTaF6gSPK9gzS4gEePzXf8cZoBt1XyQvkIM4uweXqVGXBaKU40wmQFmcD9o0skJ6cVPCIHika2W9kIwsd5cCIJzVMLm4u0pCIlryp@@rNosVA0xY/mBw6R4qM7qYEjXdA9emJCtZqyPbPfB6Q5LT6akQONtL9XpJ8I0ndrmGY9QJ77K7f8lTl/lftzpGahVGjgZ4FK4UBy5GoW7obJs2DJW2lVGCkvKpR0SwWVZBa2vC6sq3pOw5oFrgZFybky8NiZ81BCPi@XlD732ZiLEzB44F/j/oK/dVHyAZZzYR/Mp49fSRSQSYtnxVqTBS5Vbat/nzdagQ@ymQzUZIxHx/ImtuOVUuzBFOIENDgc56dqW63MoCQ0X@JQnZGrOw9kVSgZ92OLaPBdjLcq1pI6EqISpZkgwk1owyKkQ94bIRAEExmN@TX3/y3u6rbaSJL0tesp0hI2KiypJGzwjwxuAcJWLwYPErY5YKsLqSS0LSRaJUBqmz2ze7EvsHu/j7CvMu8wV/sUs/FFZGb9IGz6@JxpLlBVZWZkZGRE/sVPrpvCM114FgOLXPdNteIFeUPAqWlpEV@DX@RX/DPCnkTO5MvOT7wnmE@l8eLdnCQQD7r3M/PJlBxN4C4iH3WjvjGLRHXP0hDnDxK7sVNgW2cgPthdHIPft@NEfKAwI8UNutsUTekoQ9mw721diMRr5x/ekvPapzX2@SCYqiq2GT57YTkJB3eEmA0R04kjyYQX5@cDaB15wXfFLtQ6RMjyCtQtEcTYzF506rDskfx5PGmHdCpUVHuAfAUDkSghvOjhjnModhDKiYZWnLj0J0WnOpzJgQbJzONlcTMP1EUoWlPa7ffiSEjPifSA0uG53w6KDq3RQlr9ONLUrsi3Pk@H3wjCitGU9sJx/nLRb/@6@Rr63Kfl0uNyjGSXWh1cKj5@EjlYEZFMwnKJlrEr5SeOE9MNt0U3XADAvNrBRP@eeDO4DIbDwKnSjMEZQ1q0hsH4MugUHWc/sEpgwAUrQzMJP@zRxbgthzu06PKJGeElHOZFHUYchl/Mz6IubrOuLO9AaRVpm6mrL/sdENB4nHRH0A6zwgJhAoQeKHQWTIgoS65KosS6Z40Lr13OcBBF1ECck5huwpJhOJr029QzfJLlDAiUqEGiyoadFCZUX3vgwzm4OA8BuMdEFDAIGFXSt3BwtNL8D@GgdMOMjt03PePR6DdiWSFxD8Z9Gn0jAnOvcLEY7tTBzTf1hmrsbTc/VPdrip7f7e@9r2/VttTGIeu4oSjnGLbqzd4OjS5Wmy5a8z36kKk2qGSGE5zq7qGqfXy3X2s01N6@qr99t1MnaAR@v7rbrNcaeVXf3dw52GLtO0FQu3tNtVN/W29StuZenms1xZyonNrbVm9r@5tv6LW6Ud@pNw@5xu16cxeVQatfVe@q@8365sFOdV@9O9h/t9eoKTTM2ao3Nneq9be1rSLVT3Wq2vvablM13lR3dlIN3fuwW9tXbCQQa@VGjbCsbtAWFjVxO7fq@7XNJhoUPW0S8QjBnbxqvKtt1vFQ@1ij5lT3D/MaaKP2lwPKRIlqq/q2@poa5@S@QxXql82D/dpbIE2UaBxsNJr15kGzpl7v7W0xrRu1/ff1zVqjopydvQYT7KBRyytcCcZVEwyiFqXT88ZBo850q@82ac44eAd7B5c6@QMRhrCsUtEtJjDMINBaItLe/iGggg7cAXn14U2Nvu@DpkytKqgAi4rNZjwbVUhEbMabqXZrr3fqr2u7mzUk7wHMh3qj5lKH1RvIUIdBxiGxDlV6wK1GPxFe8kjM6hjOzXN3qvq2qm69rwNznZs4oFHX3MJk23yjaV5EmNzYIUp/hDMD/yx@sNK9@ekyQNTJmycy889obMSkzb2tGs3IOlhVJko4oFnnWSqUUjyNZhqbSK@JkDWd4OSi1@oPuyP4mNpicvBxFvbyuODExfUOx843bhXR5ytcIJtttd5XW7TRbbRabv4uJRNofK@EPgb/Vi5XtxHh77HzxsHPixdC95cJQq0/1IpONtSDAgI5hfoPxfTNPwtc5XmdQBeD8z4Am6OjUNQmp1Cl0NDIzo64ryKqkk8m@L2v2YEL5gz4YruFc1JYRnKmUUj/hl@jF5kcYh9odJbjLs/DJpbR6P8emGqkEg6JwP90RIJ@l6sshkHway9XileHPX@xNxp1cq5rynDeCe0Dezn3O8VPgl6qeCFdnpFltbOOmB@afTcvYaz@WZNM6X4pjrllOfxrTfjHNdhIzAecmnJVfFitDy1zD6U4LJLySoe2gHsFdzLWfG@rH@sfsJsrLT@ppL6/sd9FtmAviOi0NOEdcblP/PPmk2QgAeNYHESSvo6Q4XmxMsbexGa@ooynyMRXCvBcfRrwvE4koYXshT@I14nZeNyfxrGncfj1fvXtxsH2Ng2dwPbJs5WnqxXHht36mJffQ9TD4V056tg5zeO0TuOkmJRs0sKHJSUWZDtif2Zgz0NGxFM3ncYfEefB2m0kLZkwkKG5IS5vGcJELxOADhnFATjuO4Zf50qmZoBcoqkuWnPmT3mJ79NaiXlAG7MMZtxrU/wDbCv@RsRtgzQDaRbjoLrEubS74HEvs21MRXlzw4F7kKWYMXwsYdwsDfioi@1n4V3Lb5q3Y70Yiikj5JW7nUsSEvfTWChjVzEUyX7HcUb0ATBHD6MvHzW/0eOhDnDH4e78cFKdNIiM27Ykzqmjw2jd6CMN@dP6GnXRw4e2ppcKp/yuRoplTx8n28AgMWlgVD7BqHBNpQBXbByRdJVsAfvToqu@CKcieAfgVDTH6nfi3HnN0VAqJn6IfjdRKZTAskFOhGpXtg7HZDm0cSwMORNk@iF6MPw/kSZz4L@kHSdBj6gVCwJ4J0oyVKEVbV@ZKP0ro2iIaTciasY/HUZgruMdc2obprU3U/GvIRLo3pmZD4cc9rCbm0MAMDkONuLya03STn3aOv2UcXVx6EmG7bPznNJzhZkqbsAtrH7K87Irb3QreHGVK2dNsQp3qKj6STZuJyz1tGVKbeXVgzAj4FwT/8Nb4gMQK/DMpaditZrmrJKWMjMO6FBLsQmnYyMm0bL0@lat3ZKKhchMjP1a82UIRaDXgc/NdvJFHyMl5rnJiItyPVaTo@AhDji2yZh8dMi6EzbEHASA86DDhyG4C2RyhQliINA5VF8ETeUesKEIKomsDqM4gxhu3SKRlqfVK4s9n0yCQy32B0OJUB/IqZbJUZQAHxrDuLt8Ub31Z4Ty4G7NFhbzlhqjPGwXUZkcS@jyuPekPRqNaenoo92EY74/c4vqgz50CIbhxVjHL6T5rD/WJxJm0U/VYNkku3eeZiRwO6MW9ifwVugUmT@4SWcBLEQlPMm0sKpyxLyGR9fNoWN/@qisci@jlJdEEw5LykR8qVbV16@SSwiqQ4YGTMF@aDcXbLPJ9UDvYMXvajT@FXM/lkDDTtCxkUljIPksUDqpPuQYj@2JNP18FPKJBnUFTkAsJcpykGYNVWmOfqrZSds1ZaLomIhdyi354/VYJjXWUlRRxLi6dmK@1QJ1Jqi0rEOD2mCh5eUVRmXehuv61s0YRwtNqq1V5nhoh5QXsohYe2CWjniScdM@HeJJH/KvPQghPfQFOm69BAXCWLNCr3pznGP8YFPwoR@MO/EzUVrJdPxzHL/x1mc0ZF40R4c67F/bn4TBjHYAba8/9RhGK/fz6HTY2hwN/F5/1Pdpn4bw7VMZ8fA440d0WG88ugr5Sh9O6MQydWbRs8SXkTBseLd6yUosNFc4Cc5zcTOFyXhWPZUwEXxyDiNAZecr5u/zdIw0W@bJSlTISfqfsj1e2a3cWvZxeV5h0egDgB7g1lMWFOJDOmHHpJjzaeVGhpNvZYjheKIKyndvsdhLYPycSMRqmATGBpkbZgnxRmBndivGR51pvsMxCMcItBRsBbiLJszx57yPu2xpFHkFS4EXqvysFCsqWpQp4hDiYXY7uZef/snYEwI/gH758TxumccIPMR1TbSlUPYrOsoo4cLmgX0eo3kkplGs36NZaJAA2pqmoSaTZ7dRgy1/aFGkw@zd4EpIZI42PrglLteiIac1czGpLKpFl@N2YAlSneRKtzNs8D37WRZ@KHHl5AwD06aGnIshfRup2kQlXNyZMq@Noywxlb8vMcvLd@21FAHX5pmcxS6GzWXMyoU9UPoyv0KtNRrTYJxJUU@beiyGk9H54h2pd@vYMTcy2zxat133u4bAwmxrNFkudZi0azM8zipOGp8U0yQpxpZmxEPYvvKzZfM0EadrLcjbWmv2HTrcRrPIbspOKra/OyL7mBQvYdFrJhorUow7gpRW7PejFjW8dfsIomHK9qrFI0YLQ0ZrJo8xUCkyWSrdnULMfRr3FD06RDnU2yHaxfvnVqKmjeRMyFOTlAhyCXoicDucNmlcOu/C@AJh4mSFawcpu@Cc5mesyisXThBkGAkCEKvioBCdQ8kJbtRZKT7i2wG6uRashcoYiehpPW7hYIP@W4JxVH59uKMtHlqzQvlTRSBNLSTaVXCub0Ey/ub0etSaMpQbpCARn0MK26IbY9Pp3Vv1o22hfARBSnOytvQt5dEYVz0ibOhfPKk1xRo4qkqXTEhUUhBaPDSQLNAupTcIZLuK1V9/LBwP6wYtRrSBkM85/DzSJRDOe7VkqY0i084MWVxNbpE2VxXWpUjEUPIO8mtRlKUub1wJQCAYU/m1MkFAWFPGHkoBDr0T57wEorqPqOBaGWJJHzkqamTnOScdRNUZnqzEcpTm5Xgeh1GYC4QWFvPzRIjQmmV@lggKTXRzcYnleDq/PVEOWhAb3heKU1foXknS0PacEJAeGVs7ohyVVb6kOZgTn6y4iUTL35z6vBRLLaVTiT4Ww6NCOZ36rJRITVS7vJwsmihJ9HDjtSYSiRRuHGE7KvzYH7umxEOeW5vQ2CYjscrQ9tlDbKWusG8r/muoXrJTtlljGHhxz3Cz/WrJFSuJoOzfDsCudNz/yo831himGkT0VQEcls74uuRkP8gL1gxmerQKG10TaM/GJzBb2lFXvW9ubyeivp7MjJ3RWTBeKZVK4OGTeOx7Y1qNk6T@yEvm9roXg4F3fvXz@P2Jx0M/LrgfhKMXZgMdUI@QTITF0bgnF0MAB8qK3AXtx4qt/kW3G7@BAQpK9B31muTUwRAUzz99a/PyvsnnPwxSz6@/oIFo3y/KCt@VL@tMDcVooag0LIIvM0Z5RuTBhy7Ms62iioFhXDbGTDRtuWvrXzCB4GIT7iyOXux@iayTM2@CwWCUVx9wJzACBdy7ThfY3o4XKEkWKBjZufci5HC0eRVc9gcxt2JkibM6wJl5yVwzYcLCIzT@ftCrTc9zmaPPGZpVqMmP0MxHCE@dV5lextWx4u8AVviQ0L5T7jP/PNdmOqUz00yvBTh6Iowel/Nztz6JLC4fiWmafT83iDof3SLHaqCmu7wUMKHsuXu5Jbdkt8TNHE/LXdCwJDA0Tgi5crcS8DT780bFy0m3e7dBkW8BkI79pw@IrAJgCdTiR/REEO1/KZBYb6fiicj6Bnd13Bx3UKCFAo7zoL3221WuWq2qhfNHj1S1ukEPhYKqblTVFj5sbKgtet/A@8O15ZWVioy5W@4X@rhhPl6rDYLBB5yP2qfjLXqltDW4jcFYG1284K0t5CsLrbWX65XQO6puwKufnv7@7//59//4L6@qX/4HLxv8cvTZZioWi95C@8vCw@sK3o@2Pi0unBwtnH9a7FXAZf/goOGj@qTgR9ajxfGJk5VZIPaVzUjNNpuDz@iiylznd@aPf6XR5YXKtkMvq7@GcnEUj7HZdhD7HsCN8oR28ObOgfROnpDIEtAZTuOpd9oB7O9oviFKEi4wA5Xyolox5/aIBmMzWKVKVgfi4SXrZQCXliiQAlxxacYq9IdhMMQB@CUveaV5juPTb3/S0vzrfX4b9jZGU7V0nFNLJbWUV0uZDP@UV5/TV3fB68M5V7LRbiCTyVNKpFmAlaEK@7zO4@0DX7WTIrfjLPCNPYBkolRwZnGCy9vNH/vKyH1rYc@5h/sylZyQsI4JRbJfFobX1C1fKMd1JuFpwwuFlt7EcGUxhYrtX6yA/FDsAKKaz4QgL0ZUJRR97JCMJ8980X3t8GVCDBhk3X@9zXKPDzQXLQy1yXNiK4Vbjth6Xr5ibqyILzSjjRSpP0KA9SmymyyxI@FidtERI@9YK7mZ4oQdb59mPjF1mAUTY5ouhf5NxZhAjLnjhFsYarcWbcct2hWV6VvtSqyqTNr0WzmxImcXg0n/XHsrcO0QqC@2tmuRJPQoAxI4ErL/xU0J43MCEygq1S1yV9ZMdUZoukjCUHumUwe7RVEcxYjgfc6RbH9NybbrsZOIYQfhAUbKWvJ1/f4g1EFXxkzsnj8@weWAfpfvU5uI2oyP83DHaQrjUdciXWTIbHEeyTM1JXs@9ntnfl5ld0fNsT@r07RFK59Ju@hSCxGBCUhA@HTV85pnEJYW6S5hitimsOEQ7i4YzPTtaNK3Getygi41oqCjrkAIEuzElAy@JvoqRceIq/9AJ8RRvjF4W2WkHmJ55IWhkYaUiXvNsJjdEB3H1BCXHSs4GUdQtZJpeEEXusBEe8Z6XxrJBwgRoOvOaCdA7Ymw@hz1Y3bqBUM/MTmdDxzj5@9VlMyLkGe@iVKMkRxz5Wk5uvAOWNE68nMyCITMTSaakXMvl7t3HOrb3LLxeYRjfFtTfM9XfXv/HN9fxo4h6mDYl8EyNUNFV2AUVZ0N/wlCd@D3CL/ZlT8DKx5nc6/ue@7R5@Php6Xc8fDr8e8uY6KHZDPLFlRW67LNiKVlhWZGL594NUZpoYk0eDxMZjgeKnFhiZGAEPFyR5@9T189Qug4i7vmj7NCkESXARPv2/V5AO/dQDObxMLLOvfcJdd0fu5V2VU0t/Iv@lA@uPJLWJhNJZ/S0z5n3CVQ7Kb724V4nITes@XSk@XyE9oJ9YJpYRxcYL4thBcnwZSWEiG2szT1HP@e4IYEIa6noV@hj1Nqp9xqIq4nofZR0kOoFnOux7FsRWWKwhOUn6jM0VLh4eLaPD50jzARzCtiOZOXQ0GJ5WCM@3KYP8PRGerxQ4xraecQ4UgYGYiJCJ@gFgDZ3L1yG4e6RlwW2c2pqDYRupWBUPd62dhsMRwNC3qx5hYXK1hEw2lm8Kz0rJSW0RsimpDQBb2YWryvyuuvnv7tv/d@y06y68vehzH9TrK/ZVefZeWRHujtsXm7zK5nXyLb6nV25tEemB6f/u1/qfz6zwQHKbOX9G99xcBanWXXC2tc5Gt2fZUeysvLVO///fWv1IYF2bHhKtaFVl4xYhVDkU1/yLxL6aqOVsq2dDEaVtgvCzDEwJD25vQCu6jp8rMSn9JltVHFZaADXxlzFD3Fs13WhC2F5CTDmFPQykgKrKGCgoA0FhRdFTPdMFYbYN4ITfXLg@JqSDuAX7Q1h63SWm48CGExtCDbIurAnNRI@3l5WC@9yljrjhcZY1JSMUtIbO30WPvsceX/AQ)

Picking up where Chance [left off](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39985771#39985771).
Main trouble with Pari/GP was `#/*` on the second line. That code is now gone (because of Pascal), the rest is much easier.

Syntax errors are non-fatal in Pari/GP.
Pari/GP has `/**/` comments, so the bulk of polyglot is hidden in the C comment that starts on the first line. This comment ends on line 554, and after that
only `#if 0` lines cause some trouble because they print `2` for some reason. This is fixed by turning them into `#if!1`.

Main Pari/GP code can be placed into one of the inactive preprocessor blocks, I inserted it after SQLite code:

```
print1(292                       )
quit
```

Using `print1` instead of `print` because of SILOS. Replaced `p;` with `_;` in SQLite code to fix alphuck, `_` is for SILOS.

*Parens are just getting uglier and uglier.*
How parens occupy columns:

```
1        10        20        30        40        50        60        70
1110111111111111111111111111111111110111110001011011001110000100000001
```

So, in the first 40 columns only 2 are left that have no parens.

Answer (score 7):

## 294. [Ring](https://github.com/ring-lang/ring), 13710 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                         @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 111111111111     # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMMMnnMnnnMn MMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#**#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#|9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 9
#9   
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#>   
#{   
#    
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'  WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp         ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx Cr u Uitharbody+/+--- $ 165"6c"2:1*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]R 8ogre;b:ui ca34
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/
endif #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#<<<##>\
"""#";   print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQfxINDNZpP3cm53s4dk374zIBpdAApAXQJVaFSBBJpkx8ysPdas5LU8O6sYjbS6o1lrLVkbsfKG1xp5pd0I6euGYj/pB7QeDofCofkH43NOZhUKIAB2j6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4abu/nP4/gw545/Wm373jMM12PtUfWhTlS2cMpe2BYbk7PSBKG2h11xwPT9tySFGEaY65njDzWN@zu2OiaLAKuOpvZO1bfM0dJ5poma5p95xL8M4zZ5iU7tFtWGyAxzzk3beuNOQK/LGOPzP714NpjLWcwMOy2y4Yjy/bIN8fYMwMsnXHrnBlN1xsZLc9ybPDKM/bc7huDZttgFHw4MnmkbQagWucUZ96nwNgTZ@SakILTMl3XQcciOBojy3m8@/SThfBamn1iAFLDvjlZSF7T2AvLHLUXY@js89ODg0XXDPtMcWx2cBslLct2x55z6C3Cz7HdrmkbTFeLqr7omQdiema/kC6k57zA78AaQWkaotRKs5Kxx4OmOQLiiyK8tLyeChFOHU5w5tj9KTMnAAxw7EAw02MWlhbLpdMYEv5PzJZjt2fgwckEOADXHAy9KVOY7QgeAC9nxNyh0TKVttm3BpZntlnfAuycjsDGZVDg7NycXjojKHiFsyIh4g7NltWxMIrIgSshsz0ym@Muc8becAzouaxtuUazD8GaU9Y2O8a47yVZE/yAeOR@2TNtgZJldzEfL2YuCMGGKsCx39SANla/zwCdc0QHk3bZDnpcojsGbZqEpdlGUPszcgEko@/6uZ9PeC4ZjPds5HRHxgAYtW0SDT4/fMbcljMCG/wwLK8F68C0DI/t7LDo/tNHUVYNyKiOmlJA0gq7YoxFfE92YfTHpssGxhTStj2oXMyh8vNjSBCcRTeiJRbNZJieZtksy0JlKzA9l2ZQJYpggFqrZzT45ZleYFkN@D4XTWI6nZHRtfomh9J1@h0EtI0cq@eYDu90Nprkvi1KY5tlCiy/zbZzbBveRVbUIRGEmGVaMQe/PPwAQhEw0OCXyfKUArZAdoIssD3WMQZWf8qhD4cIvsVyGtsGiICmBpD1AkAo6ghh/gnD83pA2J5xASCVvnWO4sIMJAaWVgo@qa2tFIkslI08Sbdn9vuYKhAKSJQrsG1INQ@ZzkLKQEe9oPuZ7/Yo@4TXdhp@gOM25LgA5E0DpdJIqm34gR3EkA7yRgfhooO80DVw18GcQagQLg9@eSirfEBavU20BekKcTUkJgoUDWkA0RgUXSbLoPCyULwZLN5chgGegMB2noFMKWiskGWFbQbkKqYZkF4DZLDsNZBlGiChITAoUg3KVANENGAWDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9eLM9YC3PQcZDKXIZ7T81B42@AHxNIBVx24RQds9QL4Y9wCEK6ALLntE8LoD3sG0gJKABkZWA0IkgOcCDaEB7O@neEsRaGbpme1pBsJahVvAcMSx5ceKAFAmjCDYQMKDDjjnlggAeMgkOaF1dg1@8BFIENaBpiRbaG2o@Tw4VieinIWminTucCGlKr/XDIuiYjmCFtRkFdtczRiGBYaWzdJwsQdN13z9Rjb2hleHZBOJgjWjmH1AwSo6hgetQPwjbqQ3nQe7c7IGVD9GqCw6DvOcIXYBdF0iYA@dS7NGeozyWUMh32Q5@BuAiHGRh@QuTRIHyB1IZwqRwgiYbxWzwKAlBTIVWtktoj2IusQOwMSeB7FEtOr9zII5WGoWciwoQNC1cU49rjfL0FzZ7ZYpppqmxcpdOFNx3yTgTj4jQm0hwJE04C2nBpTxCKAdE9XqZk69UvWdQbzWePi5TDIes/CJqB/aUyh9DogWcyJMQCNg2GzbkPDPQCO4SWIJeHyhueQtR076gVQLkfQvEKmg5wAyD7RxLMGJuhjDkTBEs8S0ijcCLPmFFiZqJVVSR3jmCwQSpUWCcUdsiEHXlmgYWuPW0g1TNuyiYOgQXCptaoCXK50qmiAKjcyjTYPhtoFYhTSj6C1M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbBW3HVZmFaiEwfNfpAI9REw2qBkSdpdOivGPOA6eJ2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4ZuIN@AmgdpAvQxjpfWuwNePZ7Luu3xqPRlE2GUADWAEJ5LafTAaZ9Yw57AIIN2qw1bUGthFwi00hthyRQa7iQ5cC2aUIY24Rs7z37BuuaQG1okTuAKXH6LAPDIWWBSGHYvLW2DaAUZqE1nBJZAEwQo@M4Krq3HdMlHgFtJqjxmJhrdqlGQPXqzGTQALUPYE7QCGxgWRA4olYhfExQWpoZTEoU/iemDTWmBcwIdR2KD/XRXdYB3T/UWKNyZ7Ra5tAT7OGQFLPskEJzdIAKDbkqApjq9qTNB6CLzWEgQVDJ55xQC26ck3BFRZ/0LANFrOhgQJtum4EKy7hA6U9vJQ8hLhZSl19hmDkMXskrcBhSTUDtjmTD2EMJgkLRavVQBHooZEjLgEo2Gt/OPriFkx8NmNIJ0kZsNJA2kpoKnBCP1TAU@PVvA1KHfYRVnXPAoHMOd4A23MESyE6AZL8ddlVThgqy8C6gA8d2lkAFYgZwMci8D5UFMeMJSg2jHzAjVRd3roxQTs/6vth@QdM5HDojqBlc6ExRkvEiC3GXw/spsaCJiEO/eb5FhZYiiu285/E@17AP/SCqYlhTQZ80QFKAEOM9AJB5Dk8xhDDVeoIl8Lskic@ZCZpQ2zZRJTVGUw4EsgetMiQ0ZdZoBGLwAtsG3vT4bYhKfApNgdFuo2RFclC9X0xcRY7eGzetyWI3o4WO6peudGGMWAd7GCPQNaASxaIdNxovkzvFDHnJKWfopSgqf8sQkAKpUOSxDnRaoCE4AEFzMrVbMXmuislJJo@9TkGOgwEjctWMfc0YeovYfQluyDSDc6jXZCuzLrTaigJvBd0IE/RIqehhjEC9gEoIWnax2G4a7Bqkx4gpkz2KjWohfTU1G6Rl2u0gLUEIxCWcX5Un4Y5aZFBCrRrmAINTzqmRmCPge1KCIsrgkEqJ9hMdSMnjfqTOcMexTcMDLMY1kDi7ClR0aABihIwFOofVsryG0FLu3fP1lY1KBZgNlCgQm@14WLn3x1FUkNQQWCUlRCSies6Jh3UjFof8YuAbjg1oS8CplSq78nojqHFkv5EgEJBVspGTfcKKcn5qnY/biwVtoyMGkrHWga5ktTy5LEHjz2tDZR1Vo3NUBeU/ilRF5sX4BPoW85IrFqgsgo1MF7XeikAlVMIxxEDw6lIS8ajCbcbQe9NWX6gE3ASVnUujJqB/LnrqgSBKCp3Ar7S3aioHgtWBw2HPdk8/rYi6yD1TTcsuzTn0nZbRJ@dNDC77cR8fPjzePf5GYwmMvtUsLTqkrGwhj03teKJ07XEqq@qlzTCMGeBHjfWwMeJ8GFkS3kxxJiFVadqCxmXik/Po@LNFkoAmhOSgFMCMvwWVhocBpUtqGm5voRFm3UQCkgyi@GGZcsh8mIEBUUd/w8fn2fjNGyy8RaSGwh0x648NDsB3TB3afjwVPRcUMN@r2eEtIsUFLdSycfxzZgqH9PH5BLXmRWRIlQ6xzCdHB/vHFQLbM9xzs99XKEjK9UCXMkZtFXi@P26b0rIwIP7A1GIJdYY46tOE61ICt1pzBJ6VLVsBHwBgF0d1mNIf@Flze4D73mLeyFVpBRxAdoKwqFeG9aHWhyIawgObuBb2dJe1ouQxa6wCp6UtVuA732y1cjlzO1sMN1utWZrtMNABKcWW4@uNI/A6dxV0UWdapFCrBfonj28h7pISCV0BxcfM7TOV0nL7EvZeFItF3dQe9NCcvqm@IIknMzmeSkX9gU@15VKfMxR@f2J5sXScf7U4hIXUd3cP9Ud@YDFQRwMY1GnALji2TKMOTjS0XOAR2@k7XYdtQRyuHfoJgtq0Mpu7Xce@VUIGOmJWIzhzAfIXx2uMIbQ11hvqOFKscHeVz3oYtnsJUlrLZ5BIRCEClaLw6pfGhQHkmuX75PCb@9CIaLl0OjCn6QEShOIQudDUCrmSA1MgIVXgszSDwSzGrdrueyihaQTMtBB0QcTdmfdSR5KYampp@CUo8amlUBhUqFEdt5yoS@NwKLNwAMQdQqNN40ctLAEX@/4ecD4fqeGDDB7o01gA0K2K4tCY4fIBCIgkJhT8@KCHBRBooC0YZLKDiRQoGYpFqjd0yUH1xpGQ3mwEARV64DhIkHDCjgVIB5sGBLsgcCEyz8guzwhPiVzms3QOXQ4boTVNVlCalsfH75zxCAfqrXY4bxA8o/MwAI0yFyozGtGHPj4fQeGRKReg4Bmg/oOSD90EkJw0JmVSFgw@G4B6nouDUNB1SSs4KArwFfZgr2fYLZP3BZUBKkhMGe6zqDdK7SrfTBnKG2DQNXITM78bnpyiQj/1CUCjDMHsFPWAxOgGSR5nQIFeUF8KPR/6TZk0nHo9yLHSYrJRcYamvajPcW0vFi/THEo0qn7pWHbsKrqxsREtRavRJJjug2kHTffRlADTfTIpZMJwKpooRpJM6FujGOhWj97UfMiTeB15YIJS4Y01jBm1UilTTxo1TXx1/MahKIDyEFrBD8CJxisVNMbjcvUSh2GhbQ7lfQ9556Q1soaCBF@Dys7tggYZIgKo7thSj8wy6p3rKTKojEAhNLH5iI2iZ7X0Wf3s6qydOLuJJjF2vGxUQPeLQXqxgdodOeMhCOVatqRo9Xi8linVy81KNB3disUKSh8SMuLxjwvxhMFpHYtCr7MfOzuLAkkFdWqt3ojgTZJ6PB4QCvCAHkUb2qZYVL0qQPrNeD2eiELceDQJfYFKNAp0aSERXMo0avuciQ6gc@niIDP0WMPjhSTMabwZq@s3zWFvOgoHCHrU0ILi6Nhsog0qA01Vhhu2Nzx@WFjPafF@m8bDQcOFHXOUhcMpl9YSx/QsNTfp67cKF0pn4HhG6nMVFKIgEdlNRTeiKUVJyYx8OCTK9hPLxSps2KYzdsOjCEsHNzB1cD3tjUFY@jPiSeAqayiZrZ7DopsPADoLhnCxQcDRaIWPafsA2i0VfihETw@PGA6EmrZHU8UWyEWcRuY9Lo2Q4KLHH3fL5Yev1SC1MsVhaUzI6trOyFSAJBBDooldWgYgVZmYLT6kXu2tMUfhuwdJklJtmSARD/qOQbTl4jo01jschOKD7g1Rjs221Af50QHxqPKyGJnt1JZEEy/OqActBOQGJbEelNZAeKQcd9hWvQlElWKg9Mx5cs0N1MpL1tZ1Pd/KdUq@H3IFELsHhYQapw3qq@@laOAZF4W8z7t8vv799OjRPu8XpcbuiHpW2EduDJz2uA8czHWiY9PuJtk@8JNlOwMLyODHf3PeP3Ycj2vwYFnV6@IKsTUY9w3qzy12udbGazlNp0/dvHVRZ@HHI9foG7yD6fvufv7k8Omz56cnFbUUCpQyLgZr08YxhuXJcnoehucTaArFH/p1OWPKmzkZ2y1/oQmKGeGRR4@xWGYCZeS7b6O7X6VwfFS4F9B9gEtMoNcgeghkDRxFwCIFxGUnOFsvHK@09A26r9SvgnAahbvEBSghbK80ndwvvE5nzjlDzucKiqb@zDlLznz5yZz@F0YpxwPhWpS5MGFAeQoTLElZDCeEVzB92DP7/uzAMSgmOAIObXsf1SfbvMTReb4uxHRbqG@PbZLQOHzOWj1j5N7qkkCdGio8tBTZoHoCbVgKNRdpM8XE8FWZagp0Cfi0g8ulpwNqO/WMdqp8MgoYwxrxSY8UH1jbbACInWrZXymwKhimFI0GwQgq4QYxKJs0JXcrq8EEq0vjZRJFKUtuqvbybKKnlbPJ9n495RIROkw@O5t8nNa/kJMM13Ns3kt1zTImt5JaZOdjTK0eiA2WmMyTDMphbHecflvhA9pQ/oAxjVi7wTRisKKEBD64WCN/MYmFE9Ri0Q@Iy9A6lFtwF4quejtAaOVKAAhqwxW7Pk9eXLMatGAXqjvsW16d3aie0@hh5r3xyF5c48JVytHImLqSmIWusN3jTz6vpescgjQwcJC6wEtr4i@RAj0Y9B5ciQYmnEv3LI8adpo0tDC/mgpITWg8E9AHGDyBMgsSEjlC1K/N61leOqYHqpeJmLvTQZKZ8Ru10zc8z7Q5b/GZgtXk5kO6IpkKJX9fjA@WWJoGUUHRtNAPUCyzk9NH@8fHKnCoG4vu42BrCaqd0eqBvrEq0z4lw5kvsY/bUfYxxokzTAWqFHQmGiI@MG8ZmBu6E5A6ioKuOYqBYxzHSVvgTEPTFJErXIJAuCKi5RGNAmAxMw55ImClpfg/t3nPSeBZYlGWIEoCuWP3SkBbK66Obeu16kK7QWooBInyvictf6tsxkh8bWpx4p@RNcB5HugykRYIeajV2AZINwots8pb9rKWVor1xCar18t89g4iok5Py@nE0ixD0JMPdZOAFDgfil5ZZ2GBnp8CjcpgLI6fBjwrCb4FZEfj5vR2LZU3dTkeIKu8AQfuKS8iuWQBGUfRX7ZAIoRWOcyvVphfCxHK1nPqZC8s/ITs@AgE@cEphhjPJduoMC0e9zHjgF4YI@w6l9gzx3WtZp9WpnX6Fl/lETTWJUEYAcmnTDi5MlYMohvWZ6hnWBiz5Yh8kZ@gBPlTQwM9KcwZOcTi7AqJSaTUkYrs@hodZLapM2IDGVcDcvre@H1akI@PHUD2sVjdGNY5SGiIqWcUHWeS7Hfe5ud20Id3DFIXCzqvciGH43Gd07LPHRohDkyNtKrlUM8MYg/O@7djdiy3R6@5oAEOPKy@Cjt30OzQa0kAGigVU3DkQENwQsOG4jRSx/Sh0bglKc9PO88l2zQ7Y7tL8xVoZsrrO0IqxQIF7jSb1qqgQARcSeJ/lwQDWYk1T1ezqubXHhzggWYR5CfvE82yvrhigc3RHRopD2KJ73/5Vhvof7t0etBe4chmYGiApoAlpXRWFpaIihZ6LS9YPvM57lsGEYZMd4FsGSPIktEPDMtB07SdooC@McBBSFHiwJv4Al10DZtxzPkcgv9dnsiyYXgb5HZrVdiFFRw8KRowhu5im4jAdS7LpEgkZHkhmBM@aBvquKPAvRspf5kFI2bm5d4be2P@BnX4zkK0hvhbVzdFyHTOaGomdEiNpmWuKfKRcT5uO8rwvBuoxfklYWe5p1kjBbQSMYHUQOPy7PMMjqwuNPf@d1WwWfuauqTPXVzh2mN3qDSpb9/mNqoIgzUpjPr8vSqIJXYhBIbVVLP69HpPThTQgVHE/GkKV6cpIaJZC2TuG80pqkK9D@eyYC4SJE6llUikMysmo4bD1fGxf0rxi8XlsSdqi9Nj2chDiq@AU/jYHGVYrIm7o1ShubIGRl/R2yHjSmG@bCrzVtBgFoTimBdQaPRax@TYILXGfWM0M61h8Rke/uTEqnFu0WyIutxy@paLFbq/Smr662lmaeEaRHqF5kytZZRsQ0cU23ElMC2XAk7Lw3VmK9jqPWQaX9@Fq@hCfKI6q4jVci7xt1KD6EFnmL@XN2pvlmL1HvJJ6bf6BjTlK1uEuVFHHNW8g1cvLdek13LCni9F1Gv1l7rP1wJ/PDE8PngXZ7tW33HZCb3XEag7Airw93KeDtPSMmyFRtnD5jViyJ8YnRWo0e86/XyhmzLgtbLUx6MOin7xfV8hFwgpTbtDSPkakGNr4rtStJ@nRud3FRDt7RjhoriQcU0ru0xSiUmd1bmDvgHOCC7P2UG6QDHVFB9DXJEwzuVcGlP/@wu0HqtI67cewylp1KDgYYRiAQzeiGvZv0hq2fWptd9PKN0Cu31XJkKFe943ob2i960iZXpa@8AYWjr9/iKq0x@bY3NpX@Oo@aWJWwTX9DPeH6m0yMammALAWQdczx6EeiM6h@@FNTbVaFsrTAzotZt3azPzQm0ICvgQe8/PwPAMDbdjdO3xcK5U5zpo9vF6kvWGfpV22nPYoc@HyqHCHcrSnIrumvRb22ninTxcVVLJptNpocOEpnLmLOs6U5kg7pcWf88lTC6zlGdhcfpuFDIuT4PIEl63tFIE6av69hS4WEzZlm16U3y/pzRtOk7/Q0oKhGrbQm0MlEtan7euxG6pO2LlOZuNXrg45tHsrBq34K2N6F4CfbDfvK7Qw3NN71WaCs6mDnCma966fgQnNHN1Vyq4VROHhfiKvf5qXVIMiGhqQd1eW@u4huo0zb7BP5N8dh28oppZC29eaIhZYJw15nPFszn@yIJQGk6BWFYbOio9c2CSdY2ib7S/HLv@Z2WgiYO/Vd4T02ylJvtma1WAoQVywcb33OR0SFnyHBu6WJ4x6prYVenj8jPhukoC@9OJS4l8ODC6Jt9/vk5SzsYscJkO79nNjMtHL0p8aU4Los1GmFezBFSqc3Pq@t@lAJ9MW1Cu48HdI24Llb@Fw6DvUdtXrXu73cTaPadn98weX2wa2FZVDuBHj58XsA51wLrbazESTeF1sWF69p1@/33oiaKRC0rH6SzFaR93zOF2jw@COzWa4CE@d47fGR6XHWhYWWt65hjaJdfxnKGpkG1V0D6O9fD3Khnqz37/ooNIa7v6QBH/@4vCv7Nv2TUcbzikT2PYH7v0oqgKbXS8S2/q8DUvSHbmjLrqG2fQVIWjKhbE0KT7chHTtLxWDzeYcs42u06z1bPuQrppGp5tnaf8UR9ufa@@K1LGYsojdFb7FpB3NFWRXyph/xP8HK4qdDGAxJu1wLBGX1k2SEd7OZWhcd5y@YAomlgJx4RDtZHv@CzRVtnS67HlzYCGFkkFI7x8ZgINq3AXyzJWala0sHomhsVyjZVcSko6KuSKmQaFR1s5vjS3gC5UxTIZ/lqFUDiXhFFowcuHkFssKqIBQis0dAvuc/w1txpqaSNn98Zd97bA5CP2bVDR8LVUBO528ZgY3LrnMLfvXNJSNdodPdv/FxrPhtbMsMVnVQHo/RTumYJvA7Sxsbl2wiW3dsaFwml9xXAs@DTgA4U6Xjm61reGLn8zpbNynk4sn4Je@uJkIqfadHk3WxRZ2@zw@RE03aU8DhyawQXtRGnhbD8Or6OY5yoZF2m20wVxr/TZLLAfdpVCs3Rl0nLGCFpT5YunZtfA5d2PLQ/Xhy7hF2LmZSua7oT99bHhWl8fQ85WsSFuAOdzlKPwTmG0LYH3xOharU/nCiJAUhBYLC7ln7mKgU63y@KyZ7m4uiowrBmyQpbjTIxc14AexZKQi4P6wd73Wa3nu6qWhl428O4Mp7j5ZEqmdWPulkfjr@K7qlO5at3ZWiQux4Ph2BWf5TjQ@q3w@PTgnNzdSwuAK69B6LKe0feWj2GHBmNBPxPN5cy4Sk//ptV3uuybhTQDdQ7UM1TblzDOQ2i4n@GioZG9hBMp7fecE8UhEIXLPvc1lK2ZYYplW976cR7PwwVE/hczw9sU3BSReoxv9cGHQlBOl1Pk8d29gNlOxztafuC8E2c8aploDI4vCHcYRKrmnr/gWbQatnkZ7r@tndeBhtKxx54yGttrW4X82lahxCaFfIgNWOzr@0@ex8PcQAvE79JPTegWjt3@dGZauZpggcksG1S01XJ0PrTfy3jET1s5ptXJd8TZxSNhWiSuHznLekLPpiPTe@@uFAj/8eCR2cI5xTvTfuo8cWwHWqMhCMrBscm3EM@tAlkeEaM9xk2yQJ/2ncmcENgVjRDXNoyh2YTy7c9M79MWccCPDM9Y0RTRqCH1DAPTnbxi9Zvm6EsaDgyZV3V25xH61JxQr2M1w/A6qHitFleWcaRuro7MzeW4Q8ex@ZukbRo@2pP1UgWaAnq9/yy6imv/50YMlvbc5rN6dMGXkJhtvsd9VV5HZtPp8/eaBUu2xRcMGCPLdFOPccs0ueWzTAHty10rQ7bXypBZpwk02QvDpRn85Z2QGUht8gHrg3rGqOXgHJkwrFm6E9rnfIeYDrYT8FUFTSD8BCSW0RqLE9fuQqs/aA7otbIrESrNY7OJG5GadDiAZ0xuFyYfMxI7o0PLvYL9xL64wkqdZ7Fn0E@J391szfWw5qlqDelFknrlRDqt5FFsy2y9MXA8zSF6zUat5/whz6mnZFwxih2qRjS@nDJo4@zSmjS/rg0Umr6peL2RCcqvt27g2z@1YclMyXhg4vTz/PzMStXVcXuUWWf5THsgXEemIk4MA1kSnB7G9UNld6XmieDh/@jh11LQCDfyWf8kAxBdd8/tA/LjkS0@78OBzxzX61iTI8AbdySsEieYrRxEgQ@vGWjaWpUJKD173OfjEt3QoqxBm7pjCp1aqSh9EteeqZj2hULnSk1u58jh@8xSu3gEome2FbGtGucglMf@lrMgmPgumVoNy0ZcCaqlOGEn@axYG7qMuJe@ZAB9y/GUoUvf1NB9dvj46FQdutryXn8Pd2rc0uPm9mnrhXRosOpLYxSaCeVr1dqW66UenmjK3uNDFQOsoDef61Dgg3N2c5@VI6LiwEEjZazsBaGv6S1XED89ffI4MdsVymJ7vZEzMONh772TkyTuevnayVLvcOwDqB0dZ7Iy@uG@psWXsO9zm@YNV0nPJSmtgnRqQm8UmPFTfszDncpVyxma7dPp0PwcGk@U4O57Jp9fmcmnxoXVxVrIiisJRRWVFdV8Nh5atg2dbXMUfFeV57k1RGnZok@Kf1YuVEHNIZMaZZZrD@vWAixqMSwt1ih8WCQtfZtbPUuBmtHtoSlluH9fxDRNW0XnE6MD5cpyKwtrPsCymeO@c/Eek8ym6LwogZPiAVcp1p2LzLeVAYjuFL5w4F44grG5coHMOgCBc35phb807alhKzTLtU69KEFsXO62Nsg3zfeYqgrW/lzgMbBLZ/@C9fYs1iJj/I6ET0ehKHt7Dw/vinAsaLk@1CdPn7Nnhtsy@ncEDGNsvgfGM83oSwXHrfBArZUTre0RgNLXwusOl9fnEjsxRm3Hnk7unp6jba/YtNMRpQEstGEgvjHleGyHj0F0k2KzO99Pxnf4uKp/VmUsZiQS8fj8ccjh/Ux8J4@BB2LTJhwIe33NNsReG/AIth@JHT54xDQ07ybui5N8EDW2eSX2w5RK2g3uCZJLMhP7lYLzxfgZWZXNGJ7uA6jiYfBs099Iw@iAV3bNqIkHmaLl0mBTU@GdjWWxw4iVIMlnh8/2T053T5@f1NL1Gzku9tFxtAwDEvJ3WH6cacuQG0EIaHn5YXm0E68PydHhs6gauH6WGGRqIVeVuVzN8iPfxzibV4aRStGGspRyA/gpMk@NfEEOoBOH7eeYKC72A5b4Pqw@UVPe5KBlShNKocTSyxIeGq4L2RL@i8dfky/LZNCXJyzONwNO7DpOW6Tomuzux0/xYPfw8fPjfeYjOGODS6vt9SrFHD/@DquXYkI5dSyam66wqIgShbKqVKIHUSBMVI2yEm3jo6PngHMhmE8d3AAoYm@x2CbBBwpGg0JJ/ZdvpW6iKi6zikPYqI9UlAnKYwB2iltz/ux32/xoVn9Dvn/G@2hAai1tfJbEtrsVm@6QolTVhqtPeqejUGl/XXAG6@z0fIlO5gWuvERtZ/GclTgdfcCP7RfH4PgJEYP4xzlirxyPtIEuxYWFm@s4Dh08YWaelXGKj@GGZJXt4jH2wPPA@ogEoD62PX6Kg9jzHQE@UgMRkWSbhCw/TFgOBYzubAArN82uZTPXBlXH9ErsS@Az7PmW@A5PRalGb0XxQfP7C5SeN@iHAt46ksZNnXmpd7/6vVS3zMA8ST8E2y8LWwfMv8LNL1NY1rePrZmlH0bCxFrHseaJBzRHeodO7Lf5TtoZsfB0HV/2MWsARXNBlMbgPAX@Vmwmz@DEap9DQQGLQSmJHbQ8PXNUj/U8b1hKpZCNcBZBpVWD5oRP4avA5KnXYzyU3LHdVD6Xz2opQFK58AHSAZRd3J7EAcbjJWB86cIaVl41gb12dpiMLadZyZd5aaY2jZcZ@VWA6CaElS57iFyNQRyIMosBflURDRqIhBbHqCiPoloURVHbgZaD/LGFQbstCCGzGBCL08jEEw0neHWDN5ri6Mq438ajkWwndDjxpgCkaND8kCkuS2LT51PHA5aZ2@7KN33iEhbeSuGEr8uvJqFz1JEH1du1abZXyT8FWdQvFes9B5VJLzZ44bKVXyCIEwRRkpexbO0lO/PO7HqK8yYDNv2xYNkwM9tg/mep7gqe5fnevX1gVmzxuCskFntwYjuoIhxAZlhMT@mZlJaPz7KUzS7NksiRSAayg9v4ryE5EE0gJlqm9aUzdHf39g@/dvTs5NahUBQyuhgMJHl1J3GmqMlaPTBEw9maL5KHB6mTJw8P/IKYIZ0PSWDQR0ROtHU5mWn@CHK2xnQxa8swXMzdaoxf8I1oi/hm9HWoUaRbeGjpD0iX1nkpB7RaezFxvbCMWrncOpRm8FIh0Ht8q80tVGPxq5tafad6ZkeitzlhSUV4GVG3sBKA6czd2kwhs9/OHGYsuELoFC8/cMN1MbO8LsqbGTybBDf7ec757FQW4RDyCOXXTwZEpKSm/KAra98R16NnZwfp/IojfopJ@OyGEML59DqKh0Cd@rcloRSZnXwmDv3qGW6vbzUl/8wMfviXf0ZRcO4XP@8iFpfE2bg84Zi4P2lSmqg0dRuLo7QjWEm27hwxH15cggqN@tqzMXQ3nzlDflYiDdE/Mn3TsQPi99GYz/WZ7GvjAYTr0OfYpOESkNwKRAZKRgNUuf4EUkIcIzZJ4EFtkF4NDxMTGVcH7VxsEld75qRtdUG2x@JJkGgfa1qdBUeNYabpaDE7KlOZzUphbVX8BDdQhcn@QefNTWYIGDVDtey2OYlFL6PxUh3SR/fo5YuLaFxexkt07p04CK69eABegP62tl6SGJ6onf7pcsukRbF4W0qA2yJgfnKLf1B7saj2XInu26igLn7ijR6DEdSIWGdgDFlsbPPTbVRG1thZzE7ScSBKlR@QZbNEgrpI8CEPlVHMDpl4@x0z7CmLpSrABOjq2m38vLGGrKapah3MlEicbeIFCnugceFJEXEJ@qkQpURgK8hC0HEAjHglUTmDQxz0l/AAjxGdEbTEm86TpwFHB2lCuWbVeyx0D8a85igXiyVRoPNSsciA@26LQzUFYG/JOV@XB@qKnehAM@jQqlJkJshvS7wIpRvhiHwqtrADOpHQoXb@znYGsGZHzrV6I/zF9m2oK3gYR@n56UGjEE/JLNgK3x1ZbRz1oAPpIkGnTZySDdU0NRc0WuZ9tE8wGp5x1OB77fEIngOqMPKCSI2EybB4K9yMNzVtLdeLiKIUIGQWGwCxX6Dhg8PDvPz5pyV@y4X9z3@O987Jsc37@Uyjf5GI5tJleGnlHMuxjzfPFGWzpufSlQebdcPwzmRmpLJbjy7MXqd52E2dyTLLsGwqtaXnX58PtfzWy5r6elKXa4VK8rz@7Jw9e/bF28bbuDy5mMpnMbYdYXtH17IGGYiUtlmR4W/pQxdCLX1WddHlKABlkcjZGd4nJ2/LqVQtWod/8n0FDw9Xq6pV9X797dt4bRvyNJmeRfCaJnb0YB5eTNfjJ5ZlpdjZ0G234ef0WJ1fNBjhTyIRU5hwUGrcjQ0mHXKb7Jrd7njfmHJ3KzLGz4En4j755osXL9Dwgh725ljE59CZn0apYeQiTE/rf/bTjZvk1bPGzp99e5AyN/BzhJ/v3TxB84mW@3hj4@OHD7PZJFCJm59989k3dnd3s4@SuWe13P2skt7Y@dM/2djQ9R09tVF3Xa0erZ2ffyHr6ays/tlPoo1nz77uulgs@GSYBkZ8F@CnoU51zt7Ac95h@E/mN@2Q2UBzs/OG6ZE3EWDryJT@GhHGa2GFtKTws8G06v3t//qDo9cRL1LVUy9G8PUiryP5QoQbwQC2jG@7iFQjOxgsfxOZpiqVChi3/@u/g/jVrwEc9JnuwKua82Hlp5GqUqEo15FqHgyarkO6//e3vrVywOdBDR45u63L9@vwbNGzI@HJQ0o6lVoIrRXuafcYs72eZzr4sfjHhg8zyjZ0t49riUSirirwqA2KlNI0/YxGasI8RQMtkcC5zLgLC7nNGES4gN@LCDETcBMxFDcLB@Ix7vBiMdyLJU/5xT/OcyxF8hsPzEfVKkg@vapvVRP0bJyVSkTzRoptF2THeYADWNEzOcpesceCxFU5XdDlZDL5oIGXdrIJUlKZRGZkY5wyLDJHzwib2VjYKcL8aGwW5kPD7ePz5//7n//wz39Afz@k33/Eo5nsttVJbdViW/H6RaPKH1atytWRfHVGlgcsXSqUCinyBblUP2Za@pPraC4TPcE2IXjEgGYkeKpVfPlooK0a4S5Vbpq5CZ9qYKEQsyjLwzEhiHyiRqDFFetUlNpFnVX9DC17ag@gmGR9uyjXq3pOP4Ki02QquCLrbbrMifhDtOw@PBvwR/8bGygPAhd8b@BD7/s86JJnI8Dm7mcRVSlSi9RSZh0biSDQg43SRqGUL@mpBlsNqLwKeuQiLEfUbbWg6iA5FFbbOOYMX2cJ/zlL3Pk8V9WGMJLBwZ@iOJOIFPlHeKoSi1zBU3@7VXu71fCTronKmthR6tWEwAg@auNBPaHc3NTUl4lyWfzvVANjmZ5EmaERclK/UZSdlwCsNg82mnWieecBQufA6a02Xu4A@MRObafi7NFPpeqi1F9WazvzIARyDx4kUMw@AADVzTqLJxKbirJRW5kHAFiPMegJQAHe7NxUb2o7Nzc7O/C/Q@8b8QXXm51b//SZPSvCzPzryGhntVT1LHUm2KYOdjVVRRc1dQaGKnwhHLRAUuQtNCvsiXhsG/7h5zvY6IQuYLLJl9vJEI7Eo6FNimxtRYZM285EthgzS9qWnknlJh/n90GzqtUV7ABVlJqWz9UVLvleqayk8POhtUI@rqJoazidBm7pUtkrKXKNugLU7aIUSW1hl6LIexZFcipSNWu5bIO7SREgA7Buldyv6M2r4qt3X/2v@Dt799Xvs@Zr/Hv8Bv9ee/h32sK/49f4x07f4N@xh39Pmvj3zMW/09f4t9vEv9MB/j18jX9PPPx73sU/KVIBhXfzfrqfbqW1c@0cDBZLj1i6l@5pbRS4aZOlp@kpSw8crQ0mE/7SYLLSHZbusrSdtjUNPMHgsbSHpg58uvDXASgj@LPSaQSebjFIpY9inK5AoO81aADxM6nGoq9MUExVTU2reatRx8Ola6/OonU8p1AvZllzam6cvWIRF/TYciR1dpbiPXKmZ8t48vTNTaOx//RRo5GiiZ2zJ87R7P/oaBC2rv0fHDlPjpyBA/9HR0dPzkDFqSYeJJQH8FSqiR3xuR@plu@flRSsO341jaR27p9VMwqa8wmoeTq6JT7wmUGEb3XjTIoyBjrDZZn0kfLlRfmyTIbA@qLcALMfQATjBnAsCz0GXCDe2YsUqSCX8FxckjO@0HgJnr6JG1IvLs9QJYe@VvAP9Ahb/wH@rf9v/T95zmK1ehz6PVc3OzF64vgXj1/dXN2IdzUeiwlLbAf@0AHsGOXqpopGCnQFplosXo/f3HA3eMfiOxxgFdPYqVLkWUCQA5EgTUqXv2L/sF9MWzxneK5xaJL87GySTsfLTf8cVZwgMq5prjJeplsxNps1rf6nP6HTcu/HKVAuWy5rW4xb9KxeLmd923ahXC74ls1YrHj7qabva3nQM7LZeLxcBst9H2warAHYAoD1LTmAarpGi2p/ORLHTHCJEEvTCdN4WUFULsn37sXEBWf3d@P37unF9PV14DIcgpM259RotK1Ro4HumetruSHTPHUxB/Z04foapFY07oxiT/GOC0gopmjsY71KaRadEeR9G7yZltJnWPQM1/C8UeyNNUzKuCbTleN0BH067YzOoj/7/re/fRatVGRFJteshgAwFZbb2clnq9V8Fsz5AhBH3rzitzF0E0UtfrOZkjkBmLwZjQgvrbAd50Ixiv4sssPuV6FOu/iwq5sIlTTL5uIxEKvxK3Dx3bRikTuybD5WSBTFX2UjzqpbTPxhjzCTyG5tbz3ALuFkxYOCuHxlVrSbypVZwhG1m3JL3ByEO6HMe/cyRSBoIV0@kxqNR7unu41GRZZlnL2ElhAdSaRLeKnJcBSt0aBTrlivYebqZ9FoqfyAmEEr5FgkWhbhlCi0DaxQJBpIVge3OULGEebq37PHu3v7p0l9Bxp7/WB3L6mfPH8Y0dCam9nJO4P24/3dR0fPIcKzx/u7J/ufHH6@//wZuLvscvb48lW8Z9@waYn9kr2Qvhy9MUzTMMem2bgcjy9fsy8tq2EBGftjy7Kc7oi5ZsM0zSEE858y/FqWa3z5pTEa0sPe/fi7737837777e@/@@3vvvvtH/7sqx9@F36/C7/v8@/3/20xh@@fffU//c673/ptcPyP8Psj@P30Z1/9@rf4j@x/DL//HHL7Y/ELheM/CWD98s@@@sFPfvbVr/wIfv9K/H50@/erP13@@@F3Vv8w3g9@Z32Y7/87@P0eh@WH/f5vcTf83gr/Wzzcr/zo3a/9e/7/p@IPjb/97tf@GF/C8s9/9Kf/@d23/4OuF/7037z77vfffecH777z7Xff@d677/xT/d2v/xstHX79zrsf/sFf/eHv/dUf/o/0/7v0/r33@X/3o3/@F//bX/wff/GH4vdT@P17MP30L/4D8Ozf/sGP8f8Hf/C3f/Rj/P9f/vXf/sG//Ntf/p/J8Bvc8P/8q3/L33/9q//pb37ze3/102/9zb/86d/8xh/81f/5K//Xr/@nv/7vfv@v/4dvo@Nv/PSv/uiX//Lb3/3L7/yLv/z2Vyve3137/uo93L/6R3B5fzzfB8775OtDXb76hfD5@1BjlgrwCTD4P3v3678EPP5r3Pbfgw3@A6/vBZY5H2753swCEH5zIVLELM03DAW9kNgChXmrWKTxQt9vh6L97Kt/8ZMA/i/Ng5zzg@S@h5Vyzu97WJ3f/fhb737yT9/9@Dfe/fiXUXAr2WJyN6lo69etQT9Lyb1HOAyYf59wGBCS/@ILeE0SNAanJNDGvhABvvjiC2lynYKOTvrBNbh@QU78YdwL/Jjw8v2EO654DIfhxrRv3ETn63DSYNbEOPKGpNMXX5KWwG9iA0yA75aUy4CNUEefLT83CSmn@R4RAYt7Tmi@YAL/UrbIIhBpMklMoA8EhsSEJcDrYYJVKhWKXJlQULBinAmrFiD4BId5KggdIvE4yUYBQUweEhSIWUkcs8ZWZcIjJhBelSAQcuh0LGu6nChUHkGClckjhrAQOIF99apSLVQmVQT3llCAhBIPCScEVklMqm/BXiGYEE@KPHoLqBQqiUS1gAliJjmtkg1KU8tR5ijvCUb5RndGCznvP2DsY1kriNWWG0gwHhrfiVno@zSbch/8zxJbIjv07xvpt0UE36CkRCq8WDCxDR5fBAC4iqKqKoOfoiA2D8B7wkElKFn4JBKiWAEePj5IcIACxrJIUPkmyALpRypbH/wkquwDHj4YWsjLjYQ21UErlfPbOBr6T249/80/WfYsd8VH4jTd3NyUIlU5Ix/RxEICuqqj8xK/U@Cadw5KTM4XZXQ2aaUxp7G5@Yy621uPtuCtwf/@Bi0ATrAyEWcziqNBUcZzzT5O8N@DB1vsYygD@s7cJKYkMk4WR3eR3DuJhKxDqlUnIb0ESShBJSJA15I6qdB0RkJKJhlTKxH0Y0dHRwI1cnhZkRJQB/WMhnYciR6PxxGIoapJFWjKvyp9yUEVBpV8xVfdxJKn0Sum69kyKPllhk4srJNr0FlDx7dv3wLL0CKA0iH0qZhYD6BnC@QJDnxzWb8/9Vee69mixPuQTMvzGz1jdClYnMUlFmNbcYkvF@VIBNOLUb1QiKIpDmWixrb85SF5TTot6SiWpP1SGtk2cfjo@PCkxDhagkixAFK8TGN2ApuiJkWGwxc7ETGLLeMJ/o58gu/SDIWYXgSJGI9UpUjLRH3Zf8rSE7f70JlAfzIpy0ktj@N3cRrAY9I3nFKp8lbLbkvwJfuY4YEyfPcZ1FJc9avu7DAicfVKoTFPNAKJ81K1KlaDME2qnuyfQoTTI6bpaZVBb/Mqu61nc9mcnsnnc9u6ls0Xs/lcIQOtQj6d03WtmM0WC8XtG6n6BZuoiKsC5n6lb9pdr7eJazDks7QcIsdmLZ3EPz2TgTdATGq57frGRv9KQQTPqGCucDHNDVivFOB79hE8TPpIYh@BEzyQBq6QYWJ50uFRWawRwX3eMb5QRNZyUL3i0hkUJQcnDcNPec42BG6@uroK/aTIxje/6bFqFTp@yuGBFAHR1WP@ognFaqs9la7dbo9HJvl2GWtbn1t4x4Pattxh35hCVUmrUuTm5qYDkA4PcIqNrDxGG983LXJpgvlmYkj///MP@uzwk1CquA7eMdqV4Jp6qG/xq3al7bTo5pdyp1Kr00U@5bbadNpT1fWmIIpEQVaizb7TOo/6nhZerYcbxSopI6U2GsAJntNoVCrRVCp6X9/OlTZSo5RKBz@xWAeq6309vw2OZzZ3jXXAJYcuL@ediqW26iP1BNgW4uklPZ@72RHHoVUhT4haFRG5EviVbMc2b3AFe8nogDS8avFlSiVZzxXkcq08s2/n5XL95sHAbFsGO0vjquWrpRHzefnGDwdJm1DhaFNMbIDXj@Deh1L6LB1fETkNkQFlwlTaESewVGnZTQ3ERh1vYK7Vd/yzWaoSk3Rd0TNKRlO0DP7fYdDx//3D6/Cv4xtiZXTpFM/deQrFDeLRZo/xkFjPYaeOQ/cBPTRbK0Ls9QxaX7Q3clz37xHmoWGfc69HFj8UJPD61MCDwN2B5fVWhHg@HOCeLXP0jwZhf9AEBJEHeYCH8Br1HWdZgG32/NmKXD4JjuECYvBzuCD48eEnn56Gvqf7u3ufSnn28Ojpo4VPTgTKscf7B6eBdZv7@lFzAYhv7D9@vGgVnwg2pDgut8Fy275Bk3CB4j3oTtwTxlx@Zkyj8QXfO2O5wYI5vkmqJJ36G2qoflhNk7X4NrqJNOE7wYWCoW0XJWnIbOeSbadZ2@n3DbwLrbMBjj0DNwqY2GD36co@TPrSGfXbUMXMDekJ7kkoanjhEyIhfQpABuMWbbu0PAnPFWnjLWU4CNzEi5bHeBPgCkf4oBMaR1a35zHv0vEDSE3DYPD70Afim@HHW@/g8TTI7ZZP/3ZwKSIZnhEplIFhvZty2x7fu6c9GwF7VwvpUuksfQP8VXl4XhqaE881h@7@BHiNjdlz4H5jhEIykcKuKdsEZTAn51uyXtK2Dlg2yRpqI2JsIfG7VjUFDcAxK0ARm@VmaWxBYWay0l//5u8i026lQD5FNFnGtZEbmqSSYqcXC7lCMaMXkoViIZsD8LmkpidBdd0ugm6T1gpavpAraslCtpjJgqoEvrnithThK1FSWwQSviUAa7fwUqId0g3VHiiBfBqAvYkZcRYxAvuYySbEkfEaWmhdcPPVllWR9SyDrjpo5gDRYC0WOTjYSx8cyPJDtOA0515alttoyRXS6e2HsmySzx6oc7osOzxOAXdwyx63pNMP92R5zAHg4Wey3EPLfh4HAGTZQsve7sEBptNBi47xIdg59@GWvm/ZhmA2WjIZGkGQ5dcBOAi3yxPKEqb7aME00eeA@@yBnyx/4uOTTgOEYx6OQ/jUz@vuriwfcsvuLvrsUcZzHNXP0LJLjyyPwAIVQpa7YOhiMyfLTTBitZDlFphaUwPc8AooPCHL9gxZnnICIYlkeUKhjda5LDd8d0zm008/NXpe2@zyZzri3xagBj7WZLx/0Pzkk2a32xxNd/c/OUafvb1Pjc50PGp2myJaswGPA3HA53wwXXwAx8NGw@gv9fkMfOwFn8a0YSJuDeM14CSeLiYyaOyBzx74LJtE4dDgGUDQJj4PB/B9aDTJx3/Ih76TZlMuI6PiJne6xxHqDF2pmBwYrZFTRvukssFYNBZNTmv5dL1MHmwAqlm6fEMXOMbo3mzsSYISdTWtTSrpemVS2db5rHsnJp9N9JwlJzcG97Ui6F3GfU3PJiYl3ITpdKIsqmj3Y9q9rTexp6BfZbIl@ez@fUWuafX7ulYo5bdfbo1lOV7C9/3MdukNdLOi0MnDV7y2Xb8PytwsyvZ2wkjppe3tePkGyOFBs9kce2ajEYtdmsZ5PI7oYm8EssCvj5xSPq1yJzZJTiocKzaNlycVrcwPb2HpW7DaeFLYuOU5Iw6xC@Am99MluqBS1ooFGdJPpWLxOEgmEiLwnS1pefH10/PT0y9AZkE/T/SSnvFbz8rC@smneyp0nIQNT/hSD1A3dkbqHgqWOR9@AJXvdAqSVv0U2j7QU303XBY/cvrq/gT6rqhg@x7@uS2qOG1DPf10Ds4JdBF5yrirsEx70e2WyfAANKvNjEoVTEabxQgrZsQvqdVtVKuVRmXA75isBrE@45d0z8Acuhz3YK8jRb/CpeLCo1FJ38zCPx0P2EMeiO7M9aM1Kg@hGU@XbTz400TrJptEJlK1jWejPaw8vBqXcHzipmxWTLyLU47gTuT7dmVsu0bHfGaOcGvv4dEmtCu4wBw6BSaLb7IzurlzD7XwG6U6YvYcLjFDqTZxPGHOMWRF8oFK/nWfMFe07QEnL2@gSxN7GS@/Bttok8Xa6kPohWTL7dhD1oiDU/pV51WH6SyfLdOFRjGCZSSJgnQrZrxS/QyUGw74vFQCZAQnnANQTAngWm3yMOJD66bcrdQw8DW@dhRZritK7bouVRXlhVSFqlueRoyKO27SCZos3dT0dL48ATdtO1vusWal@XJSHlWG0Kdm5T6UvhhI4Ls5jDLQECgFcN5cs9i7X/pWfEfJVbhjmYBd90GBgHa9MpkVVaZS07P5pJ7P4rhDPgM/LalndFyUndTTxaSuQWsNrTjEh9822LPwgzDQmOsajk7E@jGZMTmZnqRVLamZWhKInn5ltV/Fk@cx0EOIaPGk5@zjbaDggIwEzEtW@BrxhL7Vj7UdZuwoxMogTcqUTyPZY0MLXgjn2DT6PHxcYZmtWH8zhoE2T8fD/Vq9VNqfDL8OXjHl9f18YjudeBOPl2MgQuMV13wtVctSFYUPUWG4AawtBl2YOx7U0huQ7yulodxAcXub2rZeqo03a4oGGUxfd3fkqlyHArthQtdBmcLVnZnCMnNroDaN1@oyraiXJZWmuCk1LaYXV@0JiEt4yrUAKA2FPETistiZ7G9uikWj23o0Go@WcXB0QxYDaiAE@Q29II2j97T7MqhYckku6hhgJktp/0o6rGXdSNhPZtmiFLmSbq5udsLDxZ@x6dRIKL71HmPdxKbEUrT8CTREtkEmRa3SAPpuZbd7vCsu4Ga7e1KkxFho9bnEzsT5CqkNxj50zVVip/qSf89wZSSkKtH5PDVWp2URpoU9LPY57vS7z6KQLWM0qOl6pl7Tt6EBBaHsB9V1rbyZSLEILr1Uq1Bu7hVgupMAI5GGRfiSej1YUs9Ck2S0JjBSPZNkmWSZWNQSK@Rw6NGETL@NkNxge1f@qEoJj4KPGSUuJWr1@NunVv@qkFF4xx8E180NlYu/cvmzV3oOSsp2fAfo/XjQLEAbl8vh8F0k9WroflMvZJ4cHtmPRgemP3ifbcjVCEtrCq4JLpeEa44P6cvFgi7r58kIexApR9i5EtVKtNqZDU@KL7dfFl4@eX70/OhAipxtXG84OLLL/BJlb@2vfR0CRjPZKGNnlcikki2L5SzVqqLt6Ow@NAUML1vuaHklfV3lTFwlj7wOPu9@6UfZyU4B7DqouSUoilxCr1a1LZ3FI8N3X/0@bj2/2v989zGLusaU/d2f/ETf/rs/@de0TiR6U3Zp6HA7AiHRqOW3I1dXw6urG3i4Xy5Sj3CksttxMPNlSVpkxtillGFsbSey@gO7nBJhtW0tHnGViBgb385F3GvhpacL4LV3xG0y9JTikf1jK6drD3aQSbRlTGK6xYgUKTx5dc0YWFrVdrdr6WRKpVjprcJ23io77C0OOr9VNtirShVnKzXcreGPrG5Vq1WEwqLVRGoryvQc@NVuyvUEo5FZ6AS@NLfsrbN5QXK2wYpFG9xNd8sVTlsudOa2bPozt1wXrL7N3PrSZTIO/adS7TbNle2YLFeFkt9KATpn8Xe/9Ou6nv@7P/nV68Z14wtoGorFYl7TIz/Xfv5zCLBmf7DfM6NBaNzIi4agR8dWXAmqtqAziffEdhgP7/fvsEfHQGuwujb009EmXaAqRCXT4IfOtGMUbAu3DyZJsaYjIeJlSQoUUFKcR91WkmCwLTyUGaqkdCV9hF7QsrIKiEvpoxkohte59/tOq@H2x6MhrSeOUTytnmT3IAqk8BGe0LMhbl0nmatoZZbauh2Vo@wS1UgpYgPTdfG8H2hFpI8gymNgeLrpiQ0N3KGLIS0bhLyKQQhP8mjXIO06pN3nERrkGqPc8wBJxrHjkWxQrqWPQDEgKligMDBrBwKUQaR8BASAPMQEYKvOdlgmzq6sRKI8O0zoBteX8svWxZY9CaMhtDbuRvUjlzEcOIFSj5c5IF@IEgbtLOToA@Ew@FRgBboFGJ1sqHHR9t33BgWw6KiMGGWN3bs3w6pSsdpxRjlC@OfWEEejqBzs5bgCML9D9XG7JCeZnUhgYX80z3ZA8QShC1yn8POZyqGoTEbrjSTB/3szLXLkQlGRRxkzIMqL14oWkAwiI9l5GbbYToVp@nacBci3APcWIUUHCQW9xLPJx6r@he95Axj@POIfiCrh9eqhET7Bt4vbQxm0dmM8jRIPCeHCQGzr5MeAoBQ79PzYQSzIitWn0B1rBH0Ymor0zxSKZbQ4RpudwUR40PJRPctwHWcujh@KhaEZfA08PUeks0HD8i0HCtQdOjYdt0NHA@CqWOAIkFHi1BKO9ti@xNOLRdlQ5DBGLp1YgpyPGNPxQXQhFMXFmcXmCDq6Pm2SzOyqrDVoM73IYsRodLqKHYCLUyRCuGniQVcjp9k3B4DSiWkyPHHGLaVSXdBrxk06YuaJBXzVO7CgKbHdlLh7K3VpnVupUzx9UXE6oEGLDbsRVIWw@vFJTHGcS99xzlnfOjf5wG1sbruzy/R8EpTWJFB29gPClnCMWM8kWRq8kzwU/Lbhs82NhWQo7kZsGr/9zWgbsQaW6DW1SdYI79W6MOwQfem5lkQv2J26/oEJtO0f7Gogck2xVboSxV2awRkAkjj6oUKnDqg4eD@MgZbmH5mARtDFzQsIoWgStjEgNFv@5mOsxZDbj6gBoLoHNQtPT/JGJdwyD5iM2rEWVD0h4G32McvoEt1nQudZiLMnAAYWfWUeOvhBVMyH67WhYFS@UwXkCtTOQRv8cM@mYD@M73M3mulkqxl7sw0BDhsdSqvCeLXwLbmQBWsH8jNlfQM884DhEkw2YnICwCbkuMxBB/EXo3Nul0iWlNhtSEmGEASpAQqpCv7Feyx0zLAEHg8Nlx@yJ85Zury8VOnAr/HIUk0Xj9518TbB1LBrgTbspDxzMBSXnFh47ZWAOzMp/MRtvGPy/oRudyzem/KvJHXcilhxEIt23Cg2jhd4smx3QAeF4AkdLjHUgUWnUrdiNKHtCv7T68krn/9KyH9KIXqDQBhDMJPkNNlKArBks3We7Fy2y8LjgiokAIdSNH1HPF9v5FsGrm@yhp0ghOPRgnTf3uyft5y@gzqJzEdXZ0nzHPohp75V2IfWBCLZ5iXbHY2MaYz84xgaGTg2JbWHTaHZJx8wQjPDrviJb9akNq3PRZ8E0aFRC@aPR3gKiHS1Hig//g/9J9x/Av4T7j@ZJeonW5vUuUqGTjeYHeR6PDzKD4lgpn6YG35U3syHIINizTQOAkNO59xu4NeqUGyf3twG5VjxGQN4YggEN2Op2suz2lndds3LrXoi1QVml4kQUOIAulYnml62AzNSv3/RHzrunJONZ4ZBqyTwRqdWT3AD5xXMY1BAxBicXhYe89QdqHwYiCsEIsMAAfUw8ETVYNeLWfFycIAkeQLj1OQZjTliNYFMnbQv4SXcQF3ipOeEDQOqhwChe5AlQBN8mF9z@EHrvnR4McKbZv2wCp0NPcDjRqL1KFByoapwWVOmQgphpSg@mkB2VFcri1nx/aEoagteoWzeiPIPo7/xweh3oF4sx54YljcYZSlcVcyJCWq1KaoLUZVVK6FyBQxSW0bfHEHLtc/1U9FaQzJbKb@bwdPBLLiXeK9cLFT4rTgvH9oVJNtyKWCFaaUCWZxWeLXk9cInKSd4EM0V0aY@I4j4XIAAjPTSaKaINglHm1QqXHCwyYpolyEkJ4TkhEfhoScrkKyLaNB7Ci4kxeKpg3aKK75kgKfxZhTUoKHM8HI5nKP@Eo9CwolMkeZM5hAXCB5CFRv5rFVfmnothHRIaC0AQEa8BaDN72wpSYsCT1MCWyCjOCl9GcVtgg24rAAGIxFc5scFxgImoz4wKPxygtoBqLtyoibJGq42o780/8lJ39H/abcd0/MhtXnHdHLh7x/FsY6UDVXQkPahpbMokLEn81xcwzunc0TwerOeA1pd89JhsSXKNrin/Bt8U82@00wNDFwXgjc5BPf6xv3@A86IsAdDxzM8J5st8U6TRWy3LH3eZ7C6tgNdk/AxoaDrtR3TtaMeFGrL6dqWaybxJmGuspu0SoEfRiyF9WRhdFxJEkOPvBuLoDlfoarbaODdUo1GzDX7nXgpOOwXrSqyZzQqYf8XTKH4IJ4E0KNhzME70r343TDxRFsR7dRqnceOhsIzConsMpBhLdD/wbcHGgxznVnPkc7WRFW66cXoZOieM3C6oPWNXVXC2AvgD2ewESFjOCRckszALm0pdKQx1ZJYK2nERdTPPjgq@0yPGfEgvj4PYI4YSTZapDFSdrQkucbK5Hg0P72TD8f3JIzvyXp8qRe@iDPvmle454clnYnNIEDAGRqZu9HArIPcat9CZw6VwBn1Kh7hvVFs07qrNmK6C0F3RXC1A/yRDGwu2ALEP19F//UF6Efff9/iM/DCvZMpyJsBLgeM0WHkrj@3GYPgh/G4FFmSXMDaj94zLQiL1yUcoAoBaiwJLhuPBYSKOYRutxscVu0DvoPncfnULb6nNVUV7rkEp9FFkp3rq4voUaNt9o2p2Y6JkMkQXD/Hx9BhI3n1fhlHQUdCz@F9vRi0XfHAF5pxJDoPVFrBMkbyIh5fzVY8iBVwD42UE4aHq@mH/rdEMw7xVfhoNfQDolE8osq@sHD4czgdTvnJs306HtuXo7z94SWJG6HvJgjQQZyckZwlG18nPo9jQZbeo0UIwqrzWcaDIX2IeObi7TL8MBLdnVMo3FCkil/K0vwp6stL3FpX4iGu8HmSTxu9H0vexXTvzXMhVuPAZiJs78OakFuQcUFGqxULQ@Qua0vMsW/JBHSjcTp7RavSWCJQg5gk6TyLutukX8Ql7BkfwhcHnD6HLwLsml6DM5SfNxzTEpc7MPIZGMOQ1iJcQEkHKCEqcpILNEKhJN8Mwa9ugjRbK9Ns3UqzNZdmUAPmkwwFklpzSYpSwOJZVwR9s@OtkM7ohX1n@KwT2/DYjjHC0YqrqBUtWUkWvYiWQCBHzWhpPwZCOdqOlh6RwY2WTshwHi19BoZZ3YpeR0t@tcAAI7CS4QG6CxGO9la0tBeL30iecW66frpqtBSUKYS5z61EESAF5hu0Rpxisx2RTW9kQsNGSmWSIce4Sew@0ThMkn5p@Of3ItD56uiJY5xbFJglmDbXaIRaDJ4ONBv@@b1LanJJtOb7Rwe0oCkIgskkoI8XjkPgQQ2PROeFEUcMfWlGA76AIMrN0nKMWKgle090ROrAoVTI8@kT9VTSB9ox8q9B4PosEboMQ8T3y2seBC/A98MTI6/C8xY6fnKEEc7JxpeghUR9FV2TKSzreVxE6YdLiMa65wPhjZV@EF5KBDYk00GHo8k5TGzoDOeZhHxxRbwVjkODcrxSIvcuRCOpIGrmCm9yFjlDwRCu/PF12QnFQ9TmRBB61tJ1XsuCdoFkMXrNZF1IU@WVD1AIyRyo4WbrnC4aeSSMFI6LmyS1FauaIT8uT5Ik17yYhMgqnugyNjyeetB53cdzXj6s@@rHnOBYSwwBhGIGqXD56nyA/u5w/d1XqH0iLCSwTLFe3pTeVq/XtrILmPdnyd4uQPRMskfxpcpRkMKM5NA7CGnm63jtloqPSz64ks8TDaAvaPs@2YI@wR10W@xbcFioJYwu5h3PdXA811cT6rZG0r9QfaVFxZQEHJ7xANNZ1tbjyjO@rIjRh8a3jf4HF/BovoDDhYfwKAOjBZLzWj4a27TKZVa3QWxzFxSpWolxQU7TpUExzxxB3NPUbTBtCw5HjeNHR08ffwMa3e3t7bhoo6cz/LDW4lhr0I5zyLR@OmgPlnRb9CTeHYCT3TgcT7fDbpzZ8i1ZwoU1KAMGpOKzn6jjcSHLQvJ8oe5CPB42RFEB63xWDYw5qYSqjoFNtiXo6gFBTC@2ZQggvnoL9E5Sby1Op@Q3GngjaKNBzVejgYuXGg3RimHR@DPi8Z9HNlJjd0Q3kvErHi4liTais0dH7MWnu6fs9NN9dvB87zP2jaPn7MXu01Pczvzs@cPHh3sMfvtPT/bZbEQBH7wOBzuUQNdHZsvEe8jwOKwsI8h7znDK5U5sL87dT4wB@9RpmThNteMagwc9blFt06vyWPvQHZ3iGKZFVx4NLA/XW9B9PdCNReWmTTvucLk/g7BN6NMOsM87cNpWx4KwEvZ9h5bp@hu/WN@CEgR5628OTXIlCa/moaVDdIkWrsC6hOgGhMe5GwBj8PVXdOmq5fIIZltlgnDB88EUPN0/fnLCdp8@YntHTx8dnh4ePT1hB0fHYH32jcOnnwA9D09Ojw8fPkcvCvjk6NHhweHeLjlwBNIqwy3rX45dby0KKgYnqrTOceab7tYNbPOj3qjBs0uD9h66LDq2UfpYRt96Y7ajZWnsovqC@x1pqoDFNnePP/kc2nxmvsYZTn8qmNYfyM9duiJqM812KDWoLFWob2VRXaHZU7Q4zUcMpgxPjDfLtDs9RuYk84HTIp62ZTJ5D9eo4Ng338ROddkHDQltAGwE5S9YqTC66SEaTe4QyCqk1uo7ePodT40vIhQWjPrAX2pSlohiYq0MAsXtCoc2jgdp5cAB@B4cdJGsN@IBWCZw4AFYljugKnqIa0dYToQYe0djFM8szx2@HAwPaFqYbQcODw3qxRYETrzcqEgNFtyUg1v6@3SfBx/loXvGDLdlWRTFpfB410W/zyuGyW9ZApnIpxJpbRuElEHYdHCqQSx74xcMoi9wA64TMjqey2KVuMpOcXGQaVv8JpVu37D5EqjZ0h3iPVbAw1sqYoGtFdxAQhtAhg4xIN5@NI9HEO@R0ArN940HMR/eStEQayTpFjB/CdpdCDy8hcAvAgYAKXM9nRa1VLTFFME4HcHKMdcBjsRx27fh8MDO7XHLnIsgVm3FvrTevIkLIifn@kn@OkXCDorojTkCtZKmMjvOCOo4iVW6swGlYKvnDD2Ll2FsPgc040TNHITGhg1Se1WpzqWGdFhM0XbsUKJN4OIVqTaBKd8nVeJ4PnceiK/ZBX7A@dAI83V3iI7RxLtlZ3NnSZxEujRx@AUUYZorx8HPqUeYcP1TmsmOtwzvACtUqo8enilvXyXxIjAuFvjde/6iQ/wBY2JaUD1ono8WLI5Q7xI1zb/AxR03MbZYgyekJdZyHxj0A3sW9OseNMqBH19ufNsd98csupPj9XWFx1JQMonrGN1ebCbdkqzmJ5mkOHUmloCEZCcgC7I@5rskCWYgrx/gThgshTJQxEY5gv32hetRhAjxc9ccd0CyiFvqRHEH8OOsSisqZpd24s6WcHmkXsYeVhLVeGq2oISFyBnzRXTSh6zF46FlKdRe3QL3aD04kN/vD66wFjvePHwQtEdroX0QbkpiNSzeLIVgvT/Yt2vA8sbtFwILeU@uBswbydvQAk4PmDO5GQlW065P8dWtsqO6B2Cw7cURlABoKLWxTVPU/sGzMR4hHgYzU4hOTh/tHx8zmfdPIC7IPewytIUYRNgb7Nlsta1lk7BTA6Up6CwHypPvMreizX/WVealxFshKoQOkhT0CITF7HrajjXhUk@0LKRC0Op7Eog@5eaxu/JlkFsTgG@gDwjIzgotlEFpaTYjvPGx3PAicEG3JNeNw2v4aYU1b7vx7rfRNAwovCbI6OLOkuXl94LrxyU/Ha5gma/HlOE2aNLQ3kA/4QTvkoeAqjpfgmuKxS9SXGTPFeyITztc@JWe17D//gxFjMSVcK4Lh8S6UI4Falw/3vTVHFqQiM2AgSs9hSdf0Qwevognl51wgcZnjV5svgkCJRNvA3sQ5gqIXr8pB1dTx2btZCVQyMN1bZOwqflY1nF0VsAurw70Ma6Fzi@Kh8WkQNquTUr5h0mKtxJzKfk0X5oZ3xMg53O5zF2wF3PhR1f@vrB5G7IoP73BEPr3M5Du1KXhfeDcw6dJ33/GAGtIx5fW@xVmISKoOkvalLm8U2MUxg9w4eNCgAyeAo0XrC2mGmeTBdyWQ@ctUhg6BbmVh1AVDjLKa80t6t@sTw4F8p3pbXx4eryyYSBcOniDq/KfOCPXnO3KCx20EnLCbavzbuZoZFMwvp9pgFBitI1p7WY72m3HF7zyXKEnzbeFc9IRu5P4stukP9ZAidDwoop3KuLoXnlxeE/RyuGsHhw@3mdbdAheZ24sUh7J8ZDs2bDsdQiQDKZxCWw@aA/fx24JfoBD0gcJZKLdfDGiTfxO3IgioDXX6LoNsSxUyFZtsfQ7bsuw8dSPpPyxy@TkPYhIo7D7RwfxZSPr6fJcfEDOHdoxiJWUFVWmqOCGA7oIaR4EL010DzVYuFPDXym55iZsI6UV0vmiRLmzk15yUCvWk1utisyg8TXsgTseXbbPu07vosP6bPhlc9KavnnNWC7LMpCWfo8fhKrlKyk6PHIb3gVWTBPnCgTv071kZzJjKh1cihPLbNYPL2@wOBmo01zCHRILXMq2Bj4X4hY7rzKo5esVu5IuD2p2vYyb/LxExUtoiRg63INWFGQMn5mveXVsU8OjrqZ9wfBSRrpNS2wNYbQ1BFyeGCPLebz79JO50ThUAHAITKz1pgF1fp/iR7iaDfeeqLZ5GRPDZEmGHCuhgiR9RLuCNNytTuPJOBzTtgAzKJUkaLPuhN7TuPRRWh0PPYd8REIKsha7tq6lj/xtTGkaUYAgNavuo7NDcGZhYjgxxF2nfBW1onF1TcO9k/EQiBrGJHEon8ky7ilERMVerlpdclXTaPUQCbxA9JqisZ0duk4UWM1VaRQPl3IYI9owka6jESdA4DOk2QZMgjR3l7Z9SJB9tGto4C40RuXRPhlaIC@Rpog@uPybXdH@Joq/AwTghP@I61yqGOIUmhcoknzvIA0u4Dlk8x1/nGbAbZW8UD7CzCJsnl5lBpxWihONMFlBJnD/6BLJyWkFj8iBopHtVjaC8HEenEhC89TC5iItqUjJq4qf/ixaLBRN8aP5gUOk@OhOauBIF3SPnphQraZsz@z3AWlOi49m5EAj7e8V6SeC9N0aplkPkOf@yi1/Zc5f5f4cqVkoFRr4WaBSOJAcuZqFu2HyLFjyVloVRsqLCiXdUkElmYUtrwvrqp7TsGaBq0FRcq4MPHbmPJSQz8slpc99Nubi/L/FPdt2GkmSz66vSINsURJQgC1ZFgIbIWTTq4sHkGUdSaZLUKDaRkBTSIK2tWd2H/YHZt7nE@ZX5h/mab9iNi6ZWVklZKuPz5nWg6iqzIyMjIzIW1xSM7hOP@V0yd8F2fMay0jet9H68deSHeSR8ay0NYlxaXboD97wpKVTkM0SQE0huDj2N7EdC6X0wZTDCazg8JyfxLZcCqGs5tWIQzKTKG@9TWTlIuNNKo4GezHeE6wFMmJQiepcJcLNyGER6qHkpwYIgomMJpTkllXhuSw8N8BirqeqWvaCvCfg0LS4iJfQL/Ir/lPCHkVO5UsuTnzCmM@48ezdHCUQDbpPE4vJFB1N0F2EP8pGfWMWCeuexyEuHiQOjFNgXafHPtg9PAZ/qscJc6BQI8U9uusUSekwQ16x70NdiIl31r@cFeudC2vs8cCbiQpuM1zywrIiDu4YbzbAwE4UTSa4Ho8HqHWkBd8tuVDLECGFNVS3hBCNmT1r1dGyh/On8Uk6pEOhrDhEyLdoIBImBNd9vD0dFTsYzgmGVjxx8adZqzKc84EGyMyLAruZe@I6YK0p7Pb7JhLccyw9SOlg7Ha8rAVrtABWPxY3tcfyLc/T0W8EA4zBlLZpWX@69ju/VN@hPvdVPvcib5DsRqqDc9kXL0MHKyCSSijkYBm7ln9pWYZuuMO64QwCTIs9nOg/Am96N95w6FkVmDEoYwCL1sCb3HjdrGU1PK0ERrjIyqiZRD/s0fWkw4c7sOhygRnRSzhIszoMOAx/cX5mdXGHdGVpC5VWobYZuvrG7yIBlcdJb4TaYVJYYJgApgcWuvKmQJQVW0RRIt2zxIXWLld4EAXUwDgnhm5Ck2E4mvod6Bk6ybIGAIrVIGFlw24ME6ivM3DROTi7CAF0jwkpoBBQqqRv4WBJpfnvwkHIhikdu6t6xoHRb0SyAuLuTXwYfUMCU69QMQN36ODW@3pTNA93W8eVRk3A84fG4cf6Tm1HbJ@QjhsV5RTQVrw/3IPRRWvTWWt@CB8SlSaUTFCCVTk4EbVPHxq1ZlMcNkR9/8NeHaAB@EbloFWvNdOiflDdO9oh7TtAEAeHLbFX36@3IFvrME21qmJWWE4c7or9WqP6Hl4r2/W9euuEatyttw6wMtTqV8SHSqNVrx7tVRriw1Hjw2GzJrBh1k69Wd2r1PdrO1moH@oUtY@1g5Zovq/s7cUaenh8UGsIMhIwWrldAywr27CFxZqonTv1Rq3awgaFT1UgHiC4lxbND7VqHR9qn2rQnErjJC2BNmt/OoJMkCh2KvuVd9A4K/UdqkC/VI8atX1EGijRPNputuqto1ZNvDs83CFaN2uNj/VqrVkU1t5hkwh21KylBd4VRlUDDKAWpMPz9lGzTnSrH7Rgzjj6gPYONnTyMRAGsKxA0R0iMJpBYGuBSIeNE4SKdKAOSIvj9zX43kCaErUqSAW0qKi2zGxQIRCxZTZTHNTe7dXf1Q6qNUw@RDDH9WbNhg6rNzFDHQ0yToB1oNIjajX2E@DFj8CsluLcNHWnqO@Kys7HOmIucwMHNOuSW4hs1feS5lkMmGscovgjPDNwr8yDld79Tzcexp@8fyKz@IxGR0yqHu7UYEaWwaoSYcIRzDobsVBKZhrMNDoRXiMha7rexXW/7Q97I/Qx1cX44OMq6Kfx1hMb73w4s75x1Yg8X6ECyWS7/bHSho1us922048pGUHjeyXkMfi3ctmyjRgLH3feePCzucl034oQqvxcKjrJUA8VEJiTqf@cTd/cK88WjtP1ZDF03kfA6ugoYLXJJapSYGgkZ0e8mSKskk4m6N2X7EAFUwp8ttPGc1K0jKRMowD@Db@GLzw5GB9gdObjLsfBTSyh4f/mqWq4EgqJQP9kRAK/R1VmA8/7pZ/KmdXhnj/bH426KdtWZSjvFPaB/ZT9neIXXj9WPBMvT8iS2lmGzw/UvpuWMFr/LEkmZL9kJ9SyFP5rT@nHVthwzAc8NaWq6LBaHlqmnnNxtEhKCxnaAt0rqJNxzbdf@VQ/xt1crvCyGPv@Xn9n2UJ7QYxTCxPeKZU7p5/355wBBIxicQBJfBkhw3GMMsreRGe@hYyXmInuF6C5@tKjeR1IAgvZa3dg1omz8cSfmdjDOPyuUdnfPtrdhaETsX25sfZqvWjpsFuf0vx7gvVQoFeKOjaGeRzWaZRkSEkVFj4kKUa47ZD9iYEdBzNicHXVafQR4zxou42oJRMOZNjcAK9pGaKJXsJDOiQEBeB4ail@XSiZkgFSkaba2Jord0ZLfBfWSsQD0phlMKdem@E/hK3FX4m4bpBkIMliFF4XOBd2FzTuJXaVqShtbihwD2bJJhQfcxg3TQM66iL7WfSupTfJ20YvBmzKiPJK3U4lAYmncSyEsqsYsmR/oDgj8gCYoofBl0@S3@DxRAa4o3B3bjCtTJtAxl1dEs@pw8No2ehTCfm8XIIuev5c17Ql8JTflkiR7MnjZB0YxJAGQuUcjQpLIga4qOOIxKskC9i3y7b4wpyKwTsQTlFyrHwHzl3UHAmlqOKHyHcVlUIwLB3khKl2q@uwVJYTHcdCkTNCph@iB8H/A2myAP4W7DgBekgtIwjgoyhJUJlWsH0lovi3StFgaDdCapqfTkIwd2bHXOqGSe3NjP1rgASyd@bqwwmFPeylFhAAmRwPNkz51SZply5snd4mbFkc9STDztU4JeRcoaaKe3Az6@dpWnallW4FX2xh81mTUeEeFBVveeN2QVIPW6bYVl48CxIMzlbxP5wVOgDRAk9ceslWq3HOykkpU@OADLVkTDhdHTEJlqV3D2rtVoQRIjMy9kvNlyIUgC4jPvfbSbd@jASb50YjLtJMLFoUBQ8jguM2GScfGbLuggwxBx7CedalwxC8GGR6ixPEgKFTqL4Qmkg9I0MRrCS0OgzjDOJwa2eBtDSt3mrs6WQSOVRjfzTkWPUen2qpHFkO8CExNN3ls2LfnQPKg8c1m1nMWWmO0mi7iJXxsYQsj5egdEajCSwdXWw34Jj253ZWHMtDB28YXE9k/EKYz/yJPJFQi36oBpdNvHunaYZDuBNqgT9Fb4VulviDmnTloYUohyeZZdZFCphX8WhZHTr6s9W8SG2FKVtAEwpLSkTcEuvi61fOxQSVIUM9oqAf6M0F2WxSPah30OJ3O5r8gnM/LoGGXa@rI5MaIOkskDupPqQYj50pN308CuhEA7oCT0A0JfJ8kKYNVWGOfiXZSdo1JcLomBi7lFry@@vRTKqspaCikHFl7cB86xnoTKRSQYYG1cFC84U1QmXRhuvuwc0YRQuNqq1F4myoh5RNXkSUnqmlIz7xuKmfTvBJHvKXngUoPfAFddxyCYoI45oV9ar3xznCD20Kjn1v0jXPRGEl03XHePxGW5/RkHhRHR3KsH8ddxp4c9gBdBx/5hCMduqn0eWwXR0N3L4/8l3Yp2EI9xmPePg4p0fssP5kdBvQ/T6U0DUydefhM8eX4TBs@K71kkUjNFcw9cYp00xhOplXLjlMBJ2coxGg0PMV8fc4HiNNl3m5Fhayov6nZI@Xt4sPln2RX1SYNfoIQA5w5ZgFBfuQTskxyXA@Ld7LcPGtDAaOFyIjXPsBi70Ixq@BRKSGiWCskLlnlmA2AndmD2J82p2luxSDcIKBlrwdD2@lCVL0Oe3iBbcwirxBS4FNkd/IGUVZizLDOIT4MH@Y3IVXfzD2gMAPoJ9/sYhbFjECDXE9FW0p4P2KjDIKuJB5oE9jNI3EMIr5fZiFBhGg7VkcajR5/hA1yPIHFkUyzN49rkSJTMHGB6@MS7VhyGnPbZxUlsWyTXE7cAlSmaZyDzOs9z37WRJ@VOLyyRkOTFUJOWUg/RCpOkAlvMMzZl5roswxlb8vMYXCY3stRsDSIpMz47bYVEKtXMgDxef5FdVaowkMxokY9aSpx3IwHY2XH0m9B8eOhZHZFtG6Y9vfNQRmZivBZLnSJdKW5vg4L1pxfGJME6UYWZoBD@H2lZ41m8eJOCu1Ud5K7fl36PAQzUK7KT2p6P7usuzjpHiDFr1qotEiRbhjkNKi/n7ahoa3Hx5BJEzeXrVpxGjjkNGe86MBKkYmTaXHU4i4T@Ieo0cXKIf1doF2Zv88SNS4kZwKeaqSIkEukZ4YuB2dNmFcGvfQ@ALDxPEKVw9SesE5S89JlZfPXGCQYUxggLgq9jLhORSf4IadFeMjuh2gl2qjtVAeRyJ4KpsWDjrovyYYReWXhzvS4qE9z@TPiwxppiHBroJyfQuS8jeH19P2jKDcIwWI@AJS6BbdG5suH9@qH20L5AMIXJqSpaVvLo2NscUqYAP/zKT2DNfAYVWyZESiooLQpqEBZAF2Kf2Bx9tVXP35E@Z4tG6QYgQbCP6cwp9VWQLDea/nNLWxyKw7xyy2JDdLmy0yZS4SMhS/I/mlKPJSlzauAMBjjKF8KQ8QMKwpYY9KAQq9Y3JeBFHZR1CwlEexhI8UFTW081yQjkSVGV6uGTlyi3K8NmFkFgKBhcXiPCEisGZZnCWEAhPdQlyMHK8WtyfMAQtixftMcegK2StRGuqeYwLCI2GrR5TTvEjnJAdT4ss1O5Ko@ZtSX@eM1Fw8FeijMTzN5OOpG7lIaqTaQiFaNFIS6GGbtUYSgRS2ibAeFX7sj1xTzJDn2ibU2GREVhnSPnuIW6lb3Ldl/zMQW@SUrdYYCp7pGa62X22@YiUSlP3bAdiFjPtf/PHGKsNUhYi8KoDC0ilflxTvB2nBmsCZHluFG10VaE/HJ1Bb2lFPfGzt7kaivl7MlZ3RlTdZy@VyyMMXZux7ZVqNJ0n@yInmdnrXg4Ezvv1p8vHCoaEfr7IfBKNNtYH2oEdAJoLsaNLniyEQB8iKuTPSjxW3@te9nnkDAyoose@g1zinDIYgaP7xtc3Lxxad/xBIOb/@jA3E9v0stPDdurzOlFCUFgpKo0XwTUIpz4A8@KGH5tlaUUXAcFxWxkwwbdml8hecQPBiE@osil5sfwmtkxPvvcFglBbHeEEwBgp4chcvsLtrFshxFlQwknPvdUDhaNPCu/EHhlsxZjFZHcGpeUldM6HCwmNo/IbXr83GqcTp5wTMKtDkVWzmKoanTotEP2HLWPGPAMt8CGg/KveVO051iE7xzDDTSwEOnwCjF/n0wq1PJItNR2KSZt/PjURdjG6WYjVA021aCqhQ9tS91JIHsmviJs5m@R7SMMcwJE4YcuVxJdDT7I8bFW@mvd7jBkW6BYA79t8@IJIKgCRQih/QE4No/0cGxHo3Fk@E1zd4V8f9cQcLtLGAZT3rlH69TVUqFbE0Xl0Vlco2PGQyorJdETv4YXtb7MD7Nr4/LxXW1oo85u7YX@Djtvp4J7YBBh1wrnYuJzvwCmkldBtDY23s4iWntJQuLrVLW@Vi4JxWttGrH57@@d//@8//@YtTkS9/w5dtejn9rDNls1lnqfNl6fldEd9Pd86Xly5Ol8bny/0ictm/KGj4qD7NuKH1aHZyYSV5FjC@khmp2mZT8BlZVKjr/K7cyS8wumyKZCdwkvJrwBdH0Rib7HjGdw/dKC9gB6/uHIjv5AGJJACd42k89E7HQ/s7mG@AkoALmoFyeVatqHN7jAajM2ilSlIG4qEl642HLi1hIAV0xYUZK@MPA2@IB@A3tOTl5lmWC7/@tC351/m8H/S3RzOxcpYSKzmxkhYriQT95Ndfw1d7yfHROZezwW4gkUhDSqhZQCtDEfi0zqPtA121EyO3ZS3RjT0ISUWpoMzsBJfWmz/yleH71oK@9QTvzBR8QkI6JiyS/LI0vINu@QI57hIRTxtaKLTlJoYqMxQqun9xBeQGbAcQ1nzFBNkcQZWo6COHZHxy1BfZ1xZdJkSAkayNd7sk9/gB5qKloTR5jmyl8JYjsp7nrzg3FtkXmtDGFK4/RID0KbybzJEj4XJy2WIjb6OV1Ex2wjbbJ5mPTR3m3lSZpnOh/xIGE7Axt0m4paF0a5F23KxdEQlfa1eMqhJx029hGUWurgdTfyy9Fah2FKgvurY7liTsUQLEcDhk/@Z9CaNzAhUoKtYtfFfWXHRH2HSWhKH0TIcOtrOsODKI4HxOgWx/jcm27ZCTiGIH5gFCSlvy9Vx/EMigKxMidt@dXODlgG6P7lObstqMjvPwntMYxqOeRjpLkMniPJRnaEpyPHH7V25aJA9GrYk7r8O0BSufaSdrQwsxAhMigcInq17UPIUwt0h2CVFEN4UMh/DugsFc3o7GfZvQLifYpUoUZNQVFIIIOxElva@RvorRMeTq39EJJsr3Bm@tjJRDLI28aGgkISVMrxkSs3uiY6kaTNnRgpOwGFUtmYoXZKFrnGivSO8LI/kAQwTIuhPSCVB6Iqy/xvpxdup7QzcyOY0HlvLzd4qC50WUZ7qJko2RLHXlaT688A6xgnXk52gQCJ6bVDQj60kq9eQskLe5Jc15hGJ8a1N8xxW@vn@O7i8jxxBxNPR5sIzNUOEVGFlRJ8N/gNAbuH3Ab37rzpEVz5KpN08d@/Tz2fB8JXU2/Hr2m02YyCFZzbIZkZS6bDViSVmBmdFJR16VUVqgIg2eDaMZzoaCXVgMEgAiTur0s3P@1QGEzpJ46/xZkgkS6TLExPl2fQ6Cd@6hmYxi4SStJ/aKrTo/9SZvC5hb6Rf7kD/Y/AtYqE0lndLDPmfSA1DkpvvrNXucBM5GIfeykH8JO6G@N8tMvGucbzPB9YU3g6VEgNtZmHrOfotwQ4QQd7PALcLHGbSTbzVh15NA@ijJIVSKOdVjabaCMlnmCcgPVKZoqejhYus8Luoe0UQwLYDlVF4KBcWWgwb3pXD@DEZXWI8b4LgWdw5hjkQjAzYRoRPUDEJWd688xKG2EpdlcnPKiiqGbiUg0L1O0pgthqNhRi7W7OxyERfR6DQz2Mht5OIyek9EIxK6JBdTy09Fvvzm1T/@evhrcposF5zjCfxOk78m1zeS/AgP8PZCvd0ky8ktzLZ@l5w7sAeGx1f/@DuUL/8EcDBlvgX/ymsK1vo8Wc6UqMjXZHkdHvKFAtT7f3/@M7RhiXdseBXrUjstCLGiokjVHRLvQrqoYyt5W7ocDivkl4Uw2MAQ9ubwgnZRs8JGjk7pktKo4saTga@UOYqc4skua0qWQnySocwpYGXEBUpYQYZBKguKnjBMN5TVBjJviKb4@Vl2PYAdwM/SmkNXqS03ngVoMbTE2yLowBTXCPt5fijn3iS0dcdmQpmUFNUSErd2cqzdeFH8fw)

Ring has `#`, `//` and `/**/` comments, `#` comments are used in the polyglot. Ring has `""`, `''` and ``` `` ``` multiline strings without escapes,
`''` and ``` `` ``` strings are used in the polyglot.

Ring code is on line 23:

````
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#...
````

`\'` closes the string in Ring and shells. Using `put 294` because `?294` breaks Zsh. `` \` `` escapes `` ` `` in shells, but not in Ring.
`\` is a valid identifier in Ring. It doesn't produce `Using uninitialized variable` error because it is after `bye`. `!` detokenizes `bye` in Moorhenses. `!` is logical not
in Ring.

This is how Ring sees the polyglot:

```
['…'] put 294 bye ! \ `…` `…` `…` `…` f `…` id `…` 250
```

Adjacent literals and variables do nothing. Most of the polyglot is hidden inside `` `…` ``. `f` and `id` are two variables arising from Haskell code. There was also `catch`,
but it gives syntax error because it is a keyword in Ring. So I switched `catch` to prefix call in Haskell. `250` is from Retina 1 code.

I moved Prolog code before line 23, so Ring doesn't see it. Prolog code has `w`. To fix Grass I replaced `0v` with `0c` in Incident code and removed first `w` from the longest line.

SQLite comment now starts with `#/*` on line 14.

Answer (score 6):

## 57. [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), 1300 bytes

```
#16  "(}23!@)(" 3//*v\D@;'[af2.qc]'#)"14";n4
#/*` PkPPX (22)S"[!(>7 7*,;68*,@;'1,@␉␉␉␉ P''53'S^'q
#>␉
# >36!@␉
#`<`
#<]+<[.>-]>[
#{
#z}
#
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++EAL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2DO,2SUB#1<-#52DO,2SUB#2<-#32DOREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>+.-- -. >][4O6O@
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(}2}20l0v0x1k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0yx0y0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k10vx0v0l111111^_)0
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.|
#
[ ']56pq[' ];#//
'(p(x0 \';case $argv[1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 54;;esac;exit;0';print((eval("2\x2f5")and(9)or(13))-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>(62))or"'x"or'\{0}1{0}1{0}1{0}([9]<((((((1)(1)(1))){1}1{1}))0{1}1{1})1>0)5{(<{1}(({1}){1})>0)}{0}({1}(1))'#}#(prin 45)(bye)|/=1/24=x046(8+9+9+9+9+=!)/
__DATA__=1#"'x"//
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""#//
=begin //
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjap*///;.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597/*
#define p sizeof'p'-1?"38":"37"
#include<stdio.h>
main ( )/*/
#
#"`#"\'*/{puts (p);}/*'"`"
/*
<>{#65}//
#}
disp 49#//
#{
1}<>//
$'main'//
#-3o4o#$$$
#<R>"3"O.
=end #//
"""#"#//
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'\=#print (17)#>27.say#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#~-<~-<~-<<<~-
#sss8␛dggi2␛ `|1|6$//''25  16*///^_^_X222999"26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#zTrJdttIkufGL9QlDdIGQBIbKcqSQNCSbblHVeWSxpJd/UxSEggkSVjYjEWiJNNvrjNvDn3vyxz7P/o6X9E/UhORCS6SKLvq0O8NLYIJZGZEZOwR8G8V/JCjOLgeB3FOcprlxEv9S5pq5OU12XX8rN1sCQJblcZe4frRmOQTSvwoKXIy8gOaCa6Tky5JSigaDkiFpNTx@DJhFKcEt5DwIiA@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@zRuPAc6e68apVyrrB@LFbhECwQ4j1gFFRHWNIydgZMG6BmLn2wHBpRP4npMj@ui6RMGIYFiv4iLwSAwI0ysfDGviXIIxjkbUzSlX8bjIgcYGCZ0L7h98rrdw8NAZgmAZAoabHVslu69ASi7lCqOGRT7aImqyT6RMP5Vf7MgvnvQp0KZoSq2q62MLtE2rsUdwJ31LcT7sLeWJ2nPix2hFQTIpwGfATJQl4E1SZKbrwHEydCo5@LwGGTJGM08Eis5M9IpKKSVDsOv5wZiOcB3A/SrabQlhKdP5ursqRr0VDQPtBCXLswdOIoivADGjDR0n6HSEyJ2xA6jy8kB7/EAcI3ty92gXEWg6QhtSsqUOfZAO6gG4mlIYK2eE5a0mXwPQuPRWjCJ0rgGKy130UpLEH4GQQ9Db9Jq4FI0BrIJyP4dICqYYmQ96FI@IoTbb7e8IP0/1PfWj7qg3@jdljIe/J@Y9MqJXJHCiceGMQZHjCLY4rkuTvLQgOEmWg43cd4PsoVr6dC2bCNXd@7iZbyu9/QoO9D5ceqWHdlDtgVEhsFoNwMqJk46ZJRLPT8Feguv72GHB5T3k4jkuuUPAufgICfPABEpGp9QtcjA3UOSrie9OQHeRuogbLPeO99HDo1Xs4HLU0QI1EmN2nzUFTV88QjIeBaGiRB/CAa@PoLp3HjDhrz74NmQnC9cAjhckgodaearpjga6VzINovkxZhLg/uahm1nWIr1Y8BMY/CMGppR@LkBgoM/@OMIlTrQI@yue0c8iCUKFn/nAdQzgqOsnB4cYD36lPIcBvvNYturMY8hoYHsZoHFiLgSBupOYqBGRShpkkcXTT0CWnqUuG6grSYSoaMAnGfnFpuaAPvG87H5AJd2H6xhKqUF6ojhoQAwLMlChqAgCuCkiZmIyVW5B11yaZRoYDPBWw2wEqBPrVJndXZhP0viK0JliSevQ/UGBvCqG/vT/oURcpItf4VQrYmCPfo8cHiz8FwviAT4QxUEEkQt8@g0LMRG6zCIsAifnWYYbF8DnhTgg3Di2wSV4Ajz6GTIv8rOPAXEEedoyf2cp/xQz1b4gJtf5JI5ad12auJxp8pTxgx5ChNOS6/XBXFwFxTa89aOLGGnTw/nozNDM9h0QUHI83Dnyswm73Fn6gKyHM2x3Fg5H7LJmQYSqeE/j2UQYRzFHDhzyI0d/x340cNvrKLjrHe@gf0lBxmOqbrf0oR/pQzp6bOWbly8P2JrRcOg/tgjYgEXV/HfNsrQYruMSJEWTB9GT3OHzSZHmgerpOf7S//0PD/j9UBoT5zqDNPpiMTiL6BVKRh09KpxyK96wy3pBfioCKLG@A8N1MHV2gsVgPawd8o6CtkOSE7HKCigNAjBkYBk4mIfqDJYQFB6d/64Hynh4Nwjz3ZEfqqDLm5rBBAi3mFhgevcYlHuZBAeDFUcaxI6n8xrQp0uJct7TqTOOo2t9JaRo6fB3kDoP9mRZ9OWTIi/4FSu978nOT/D7LRMsVxrtvZfmfvnzyHogYvMx3eVmk4J3Ud8EzoU@xOHZCIbrj8oPk/pjKCvnv48t@/U4cVyqX2X4s1Zt3kKKFkCxfvzL@@Ojb@oPAwi5Wxrw61pwB5ELQS3Kvw8JThmwyx9RPKYHrhOA9rW47mGvRV1hk3@PsYEzvMbmwOSP6xBiHdfrRI2XFdCylZMkj29y3fWbeLOH7XNjqFHp96IOhA4/hOM2vZXhozrhx@qyzsq4Io2wsFzje5xLh6hu4GSgGnnJXXoJ0mCXb6kqRggXdWY5@pai3iNqXus@Vi4tdya@G0P0TpiY8SaAm8eC2v3sYQkGm3jsstyKd6W@vqaOh6H26zcVNnZzrFIeUZnf4Y14gYAl2IpeaPFjTHPjK/w@GuIn8SXl1/VR6GYtVb/D26gBUwlIch9u99zvaeuvfga@Bi4PvSBLyt6xBtiiIs0aZd8Onvlp2afJFq3QynKWRE7I6nQcz/M9izcDgA3YAYKi3YPw8z7yWb7txikvaXnfhIX6f/zdKxtjY5pnJPQzSC3HEbZyoW6dxFcvON4S@16SONhYQxjg8AKekauv9kh25efuhPfDQErv35xslc2Msq0MN0cYd1ao4OeGqRHQ4OSU1d2cGi@mXPdKxItd80OB6hdhRK58L59AlnvsRy5lzZJ5AQ@UpLgsytMYdbdBDohH0ROzguJTATlwEMcXrI5BSv7xd97CgUkABlTDeI6e9RRXMBLQGpP1TVyecM@B3NA0LpfIyGQw4AI4cg2WQ/lzhbgTh/WWUo2o884KouHdlVd7x0TdJxJ2xLHRYvkjubr37s8fesbA/kpCHbIyHUsKxjfxqfrczMQGmS@xZhSKkNVpA6aXsxIRq1OxPBZ2X1mzcaFUXOGIjGMmrnmnJGSNW6Z39Ip1Slg7LEL/hB1RKNyyHG4VBpp3UO2qDOlcCDWaepyTNr42oMASGPFWL8FGPFb9uKU6JV/IBHVFdYnZNuCOMyTARlNoL5Po1bpFf02HBYv2l02t2bLZcapndqfLRin1YmxF9k77VwM9m3Ol358@NZpTYFucwvJnOlrO/i@vb6ta1/jyJXOuiSjOJIuVd@KOSKq3RwdH@8cneyfvj4GNM6Vk4FHZY2f9Yqd8fwC6XGRzyyz5h68aWLuHvS7AzQx2lW/l0A5Q65gNzM0ZMKyUdxrXRll26nVFWXnzsT@FSAFKix1o1kEW5pTFZX90LkUw0gkv2qGSX@hhtqi/8QgjtKIABIEFJkuSMpQEQaFrZC/IQOs9D8Q4vM4przd5yb2ou8UKqTra4hQNIgq4NrMf9slAyleQGLjnfHOVrWOQs3Wt5j7V//nXv/H2cj@H8X@W4xGM/5uPT3Xk0sN@JKdxwRpky4eDI5KBa@EHD53pypl4MQ36HRWU@CFw8JIxBJdzYpfnXcKRex@AnyAEYCaqKWomw0fTgTzJ82RH19EZj@NgpLHSiU5BDqDYGlQL@ucCu/1gTPpme3PDhMycqpdzgKyJNMY8ngNUlB0iEuHST@zzoUs6nQ4RM0gEqb1pcUbqVee0JZ4vCK3CWoH77R6BPbBluQPmuuU2uerUTQW3EtsmkimRgQUumcsFrFpmA1ii4OOo5IcIbiMuWYVtEDrNCWhzej2PRxAMoKQOkU/snc8ckAqAOGxFFB7oLtALMyxZ9@/ESm1VDOKvuIyl9jviOtUhoCH/s0ZzIhj/Fx/3@ob6dbDufcVCd/YevpaQ779UwLOQ3eMoxvrtDdBK5KbebOnmprJiJ2IJCqhFq/gCIMEOwK5c6n@Kk2zv1f7Bj4dHxw/a6myldH@ZRKRup95XtUZvsBhIa3R@UY2cxBdA8Tf6y2qOK/yb1U6zX@7GNm6zq3v0Usd2l6Dp8xmIL3LnDsUK74WvHH1OA@hv@aRqioB8idAVHuSLq9TMy4kF0tWdD888d3@gP2X5DCqJ7zSxWwkxwgdKdn@iUUSviQzWFTqgtE4BaVyqNOYv1RuL1yArJ/m3shq/r3P70m0Qg2VVdYtFI2sG6nXeJ/28P@pHqGPWtf6DrunWrVwN7Gsd3ILSlasT26y3avV6NarJ1QgN49kzDGKzKtjdmSZq4hQWqdVAscDbg53a1ciqOh256tnNGtsBtxAfbmHD10zXbqvOTK8@AzVvwJOUojehcjVTMGMxNM2cAX2fYj@q6o3QSW5lkYhTfJuE6Kt@vY40aNUzJOCr3j@uA@VgNcc6C5tW6W71cWgxryTdVdbffquYm4SI8qzZerKrAPCWrtcu@693LannjJraZ3cgVRTR3BCtaEOo6LVzcnRxdPQXMJmmciz2nsjd5@R5rWFtbtUasMls7P4JPuRIktot6fhU@ixUun8CMXZbm092YXDeORcqnUG909O66qDbEyq3QuVmJlSEij3tvKvjp/e6W@ef/b2f4dpRB73k6Of9veP9RrOjVpqvDxvN4/cvKybctBd3ONWCu3f7e68P3580mnzLnw8@7L8/erP3yvf9JPO8zIsng25dU1WiaqQ76G0cbh7uCpXp03q3bud5Tj6e1UDzXnen73W1A/h/FirvcL2q9hWtO/giVHqVHrBs1jQC49KYmhfmxdv4cPl3eAgT/tT4FKfGxJiYnmmaU4O@N66nxrURxoemB78U/hkhDH1jNDXGRmREpnkHzuN/4WH89jAGUDFsy6dGjlCNEfyODw/fArARIP4E/3zDMIA@43IKlAYm@5yeKQYmJtNOtb5bV3fhY3frnfLnRcVj3NHgnEKPSIP2ZvK5hyGmouuCJCfy1CB9yWLJeBWbZD1zgKZbM2sKs7q2YVnz4YZl0cxxLTr1c8uQuBbKMr10Alls9qfNUVtUILrL2wrYi9lSFFU2MNpvKKdmpyNvtpVuV95sKjAtSlMxTqX@rTEzV75yb3vQkdnHVPifotyaMGfOFMWYj8yuobRv5Q6MZRkf4BeezRAEPoRtUmVWQQcTkY22AsGPKl9029SbG/bU2NiUt@rb5T/7iaILZ2ev9072zs5ss4KkAXcqmvVONJuihOy1MOuOA6oFEGJa24IIH2ShPaRjwIDLs4zCJzxyaEHpVVFc0cXnFZR6nz45SQ1cj6Whp2w2t7faW9ut5lZja3tro21uttsNs9kwn2893zYapmFumZtb7W2zsbWx3drY2NiG2fb2c70mVDw6wpogIRk44XgkJZJqvhBbW5A8t55DpQuOGnuqHew@x9qkK@CbAyITRa/paJvieUXsSzX9Fstd8MGKNdNrknguCgC9072tbLZneKCZ4GHHY2MbDwqmbc46XRhVJYQn4TO1FW/ElWq1Cm7gXVdsiYeaYON/7cEdyCHGIwBUyb7EbfNr9KNV2Umk1obUtyu8EJLN50ql23yuQSFQGfCH8gY8G1SY0jXNyle1w/86cEE@Z1s/eOOx3/yBnH8xv2xWdV2Smm1CzE1k8OnZ6dlfmsDg7W2xufmbrn8rIMPsIiiNKPjrIlwXlfZS/62DSXm0iEwweFtAEFzwmyDDA3@IHL/zjAth9RH7D0fwTEC6kJsyDsD83AarFEiNmeJAIbesDPFHRMZZyE9MXg7xwi8v0ogYlsAXYdfTWgwBC@oHsXEBPsQgJPu2aRG/g8DgF2JXiQE/8x11G4cBjWRGhT9QrMWaBSVd2L1Cy8r@ep0vn3Gy@Hnc0OPH5nOLWyAvxC6GK5e7lXsLoAKENVIf3I3wu48BaZa8gNAgf/gY9/ZDmFbmZ2IkLCfL50tRzIRa3ggtAY9dSyzhJ9lVbjF9sL6Gz565p0kvHFhKaOf4W6@H1ky4kH2@pJbboa2aVgLEWnmvXvcHdqj8JCeM@NA2YDHgRsiZcruQdGSX4sqUxk0vUr9Gg8abXlQ3B42iUfto3zQc22hM4QtsawSNz8C8OSvl3L6pR5bTgS9mMnc4kdhZ3bHuPMItF3Jg3/ScgW0oVgAb6/U3cBigM@sF9fpAAeQBTD7caAXPnjn1oDu1AlVVcNVp68WbXg6DQd3G@x3Z6Uxf3PQK2L8jw68NaAIFiId9d2UA8IA@C3jMxbckndM4RfKmQF5o27WPL2ofa/aTJze9qRoOGpz9O8ZS8Ej8FIlf1RG59nFVsRhLWFdDFp/6O0@1WkbEBmgfMLmRrOzkFNY@wkyytIbZ/wE)

`␉` is a literal tab, `␛` a literal ESC character; Stack Exchange would mangle the program otherwise. I recommend copying the program from the "input" box of the TIO link below, if you want to work on it.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .007019 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 1369 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

### Verification

Most of the languages are tested by the test driver shown above.

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Incident was verified to test 33 on my computer.
- Deadfish~ can be tested to output 48 [using this interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Note that Deadfish~ takes the polyglot to be fed on stdin, but and prints a number of `>>` prompts to standard output, which are an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program.
- Brain-Flak Classic does have a TIO but should be verified to run [using this interpreter](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brain-Flak/commit/efc8675ce1d4535fd9525821f668589dbea7428d) as the TIO interpreter post-dates the challenge.

## Explanation

Wise was pretty easy to add.  The current code did a whole lot of nothing.

Here is how Wise currently sees the program:

```
![][!>^>>!<<]<[>]>[<[><-][<-<-<-]>--->][>>-<---->]|[[^<-><><?>--|[][][]-^<<>>[]<><>|!-?:<><><>-<>|~:>]]~-<~-<~-<<<~-||^^
```

Since you probably are not a wise expert heres how it works

```
!  Roll the stack, its currently empty so that doesn't do much
[] Loop until zero, since we are already at zero this does nothing
[!>^>>!<<] ^ same as above but with stuff inside (This loop would surely destroy most everything on the stack if it weren't so there is no problem anyway)
<   Bitshift left, multiplies zero by 2
[>] Another loop that doesn't execute but would terminate if entered
>   Bitshift right, divides zero by 2
[<[><-][<-<-<-]>--->] Decently sized loop that is not entered (This one is dangerous, cannot be exited once entered)
[>>-<---->] Another unentered loops will exit if -1 < n < 4
|   Logical or, does nothing
[   Very long loop caused by the Nim comment enter at your own risk (this can actually encounter an interpreter bug I was not aware of until now)
 [^<-><><?>--|[][][]-^<<>>[]<><>|!-?:<><><>-<>|~:>]
]
~-<~-<~-<<<~- Push 57
||^^  Garbage noops
```

As you can see it is mostly loops that are entirely skipped because we start with a zero on the top of the stack. To make it print 57 I needed to put `~-<~-<~-<<<~-` after the last `]`.  I tried a couple of places but the best was simply as a comment in the Nim code.  There are some characters Wise cares about after the Nim code but they are all either `|` or `^`.  These are logical or and xor respectively and ultimately do nothing since there is only one item on the stack and the implicit argument of all operations is 0.  The only concern left would be that it would interfere with existing languages.  However in that particular spot it seems to do nothing to the existing languages.  I was concerned that it would have an issue with Incident, however for some bizarre reason it doesn't change anything there.

## Going forward

I get the feeling that Wise is the kind of language that will either be no problem whatsoever or a really big problem.  It cares about the characters `:?!|&^[]~-`.  If you put these characters inside of existing `[]` you should be pretty much fine, I have marked which loops are dangerous to enter in my code explanation above.  The only way you can get a non-zero value on the stack is `~` making it particularly dangerous.  Any of the loops marked as safe will wipe the value for you.  You can also add a `~` or `>` to cancel out the damage caused by a first `~` or `[>]` to pacify the TOS.  If things get really messy `[>^]` or `[>&]` will wipe the stack pretty well add more `^` or `&` to make it stronger.  It is proven that it is impossible to write a program that will arbitrarily wipe the stack so you are going to have to pick a tool to do the job well.

If you break Wise and need help fixing it I am always happy to help so feel free to contact me.

Comment: Again! Hmmm. I have an idea.

Comment: I was going to try and do unary but it is still too big

Comment: How would you do Unary, anyway?

Comment: " not a wise expert" You missed a pun opportunity here D:

Answer (score 6):

## 73. Morse Code, 1961 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*,;68*,@;'1,@1011)(22)S ␉\4n;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<.>>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsddsdoh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d@O6O4111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.
'((( p\';a=a;case $argv[1]+${a:u} in  *1*)echo 50;;*A)echo 54;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<<(65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}())wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWW li ha '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
=begin
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjap*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* --... ...--
#1""//*
#define u8 "38\0"
#define p sizeof'p'-1?u8"67":"37"
#include<stdio.h> 
main (  )  {puts(p);}//*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.
=end
"""#"
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#1 xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm
#s8␛dggi2␛`|$// '' 25  16*///~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_X2229996#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .005038 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2041 bytes)

No, I'm not joking. I wrote an [interpreter](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c) last year, and this apparently works.

The interpreter is space-delimited. I just stuck `--... ...--` on the first line with `#endif`.

## Rundown

This program prints **73** in Morse, **72** in Fortran, **71** in what, **70** in Commercial, **69** in rk-lang, **68** in Python, **67** in C11, **66** in Surface, **65** in ALGOL 68, **64** in Agony, **63** in Brian & Chuck, **62** in Grass, **61** in S.I.L.O.S, **60** in Moorhens 2.0, **59** in Tcl, **58** in Ksh, **57** in Wise, **56** in dc, **55** in Brain-Flak Classic, **54** in Zsh, **53** in Shove, **52** in COW, **51** in Assembly, **50** in Bash, **49** in Octave, **48** in Deadfish~, **47** in Lily, **46** in Cubix, **45** in PicoLisp, **44** in alphuck, **43** in reticular, **42** in evil, **41** in brainfuck, **40** in Minimal-2D, **39** in CoffeeScript, **38** in C99, **37** in C++, **36** in Labyrinth, **35** in INTERCAL, **34** in Rail, **33** in Incident, **32** in Whirl, **31** in Modular SNUSP, **30** in Whitespace, **29** in Trigger, **28** in Brain-Flak, **27** in Perl 6, **26** in 05AB1E, **25** in Pip, **24** in Thutu, **23** in Hexagony, **22** in Underload, **21** in Nim, **20** in Prelude, **19** in Reng, **18** in Cardinal, **17** in Julia, **16** in Pyth, **15** in Haystack, **14** in Turtlèd, **13** in Ruby, **12** in Fission, **11** in Befunge-98, **10** in Befunge-93, **9** in Perl 5, **8** in Retina, **7** in Japt, **6** in SMBF, **5** in Python 2, **4** in ><>, **3** in Minkolang, **2** in V/Vim, and **1** in Python 3.

## Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvLcttIll0bv9CbNMgyAJEACFKSJfEhybbU4@pyS2PJdkeRtAyBIAkLrwJAkbJMx2xnYha9780s@z96O1/RP1Jzbib4kEjJVREzEUOLQAJ5M/O@8r6SvrTT4a@/FujDTiP/ZuBHGcvcNGO9xLt2E4O9uGEHtpduVWuSxKGSqDdyvHDAsqHLvDAeZazv@W4qOXbGWizOZzGowQosce2eAJP6UcJoCAuufOYxJ47ZpW8PDYf5HmCPKzuAT6OAYDI3iRMX15SFrttjaew6Xt9z@FrMnWRumHpRmBrMc67Y2PN91nN9DFgg4JQxGRulS6/EcobUiySGjxPfQ3f@VHQBE7ozkt3YTjjJEYs5/TPKx4kdx0BSKrAzIJ55gZsyL1NS5tqpR3zEkNQNe5xb8ZzDEbPDZSrZtWczG/iOEj536iYZyDP4vGzoJi6mtGnxQWIHTB0nXgYWEDMP2alrJ@w8cV0Nq0AIburYMfC4syQWi2iFjAgxuLAaDeXo5FiB0MQIw44zqZDUzv/1R8lmRpMVL@r4NmW5Lh39@RW7LXaoDSwwGQQbJ6qtseY3lpqdjovvxLo0B8lUwqwSuOIzM4ozEzPbSQb0Fi39umrE/tKyrHFPEkuKJKB6kAV7HbL3ZU6XM0oSF1gsWGpfgWQ/CgfgJkhNRiFxI2TbFQjAicJeWmbuNXgWhUJC0Zjz93zoQWQpCcS@BHtshzgvNgFnJ7YBNC/n52zdNPJHHA4j04zUDzzBUJrxdZ@9Z33b82kI@mkqgXXipiM/ozGjsEdyD7zQ7RlshoYT9QgoiK6xnI1J@Qvsm2Bpt3GkAAwxRJxU6vrnX//WGwwwz6HjREkvV9b3rBc5owAI2xxZG4pI6hqFts/RAlyZVhfDscC17Xs9O6Plw5t8CY4EX3Ucjfwei7BgMvawsYb2NTZjv@86mStUPBplwLHMAvtK2AhP6C0ID@xLCJYvwNfmZOvs4CWk5LhCYfRglPV3mB4fMSU1P6r7e@r@044L3DRD2yia5qAObTM2@Cs8KY8pzvvDhTxJe869iHaRHw9HsBnoCdMY1iQhZjo2yEnJqGSwe2V2yRnNLREUnW/RsaskLrvEvp4RxnVE6ACN12nf5jMsZDqDu6tibm9Jw6CdULIsXTESfjTGwhw3Mp7Q6ZAWtwc2lspygg4FQWJF/uYuaVchNJ1mu3TZjn7pQTqkBzA1uTCWaAR4rSpgMJuQ3tKmCOwbzOIIE72QJPP6EHIAvU1umOPSZsCucIWdo0VGXDFSD3oU9VlFr25tfUf4WWIe6j@btv7FfFTGRPw9MR@yvjtmvh0ORvYAihyFGGI7jhtn@Q4CJWmGPXLfDPKXem7TjXQoFQ/ur81tW27tl9Yg6yOkl1tom9QejArAat3HLmd2MuA7kfW8BPvFv7m/OgCu7y0ufyKQOwh8kh9AYeaYoGTuxHVGGbYbFHk89JwhdJewC8WGFdbx/vJ4tbw6TI7eny9NyFitZ1XJMOevCI0Hp9BJoqvzwOrTVK07L7jwl188PrOdBmsmjuYowkItvTVM24Du5UyDNz@jSALmb@a6@c6ahxdzfoLBP5JjStxfRhAY9NkbhARih3O3v2QZvTRU4Cq81APXyYGTrp@/PiF/8MEVMQz4LnzZsjGPENFgeO6gqWMmBMl1hhHTQ6bkOKgy96efgZaZJg5v6EtBhKwZ4JNK/OJds4k@i9jsvkNlrVU4vqRSZm1Z7pbhw/wUKhSOfB8Po5BvMdXVbqFrjpumBjYMeGtQNALs5JKrTe8CZsMkGjN3qtWVdcv9ToG8HF16k/@HEnEIL3EFVUti4K9@ixxWAGeCkOWcdSsQnHcvo4DsPPvAKSZ8XyTwDX34Aym@yYawdLrDZLsZxS5QumNJFOCJ4FzV6jygUxTjc@SF6q3y9OlTZU9pKWW09tFqUGufWiW09nlL5y2CM6jFR5R5i3rbfAS96yrT9mzmidYl0U4oav3ixard3turdct228rvVbprcCbwHYDW6YZ5FK3ZpKamya0xCDUu@5Ig/xzC@QkhH/vJI0/cR4C4SByk@WIdSRbMqN21pfKipypi1fdmAPYZ8c36KEJenooPeOOFVxHpqBnMWhcVw9q6MwXyndWRfS8d8ssd0BW0Vnv46DS47PPLGoC9PAxATEE5EvGFmzKKRKIImj/mYEEURgIV8MsLbfMtvxnwHuvwuWuk7yDzwsWeH7j6bs289ELz0u0/BHn84sVrDtO/vPQeAgJTCO/ZfQ1YMrpcxzPEZsMVJ87ucP18lGS@3jMzurv//W89cH9VNkP7JkU0fzVvXIBpJCe9/6Co8qH0wC/rxfp55CPT@84cjk0RvO3PG@vn2mNvXeg@xBryBA@Y@j7sCVgGO7eq3NgX/qjnzu7rJ@U8vBsLiNGhF@jQ7G2jwgWIR4pvuPV5YJZ7AY2YhhKfxI/snilSUc9dSFTw3p3Ygyi8MZc8m5Fc/gZUZzEHW@Se2XCUjcSVEs7vyc6L6fvYhswhK1uHL6yj/PYAPJDYfkh3xbYhU60f@/aVeUnNiz6a60kVxCTeANnt7P4Q2Iez2HZcc5zSba3avEGk6NsJO/vzu7PTR/WHT4gQMvHFde10r0MHvjXMvj8TqPT55fcoHtcDx/ahfTWhe1Ty0ZfY5N1jrG9f3pBLG/5@HaJVB6US06NFIraoKMXxw4Mch@mwPU1nd3f9aFF84hM4EXJm93vOCB7FC0B3tbfUfFA5vEhf5H2p0CiKA9YZIfvaRlzg2yl0JMvZ7F5DLPzymM6Sq3BIeRatxzT2HlKz3Puh9G0xMvacCE495vKmBx8Pa5YJKd67HxstpqHCIr8shtJTrrivEP6QB/72qOZGTkZZ0wO68xvMkkhYKCVc0gsjeohpTjSm74Oefxhdu@K63h19WYvVbzA7us9VAkH36vCe8z1t/eClMDq4rDeHV2uxyhx/7XuyUVGCjDVlVaPyqHjWKvOZ8dr4yTgxztiZ50fpo/xAvp6m4rpelRegl4lnh7pDOrzcXj9sLWLctbFDfn1AwLY/iPztnYFp47KWN2ejpE@2/TG2PG6jLOu7NmoezUShld8fwji5wt9aTJGfBDDelN591zk8bMHyoP9huhDp08j1NB1XduY6laQPc02kFG953XheyEnLebkb77wkL2@m8xOEAnxf4vKyzixRZQUqNo0CmMYsSgzG4VTVLpU0TRKDaJMNQoDNoHgVlwppokCcMli7jMMiGWq3WfF2slfZs6asyeQ9mXW7YlZe0jmaxLz8@lYMbRftbrOo6LpSVDrhHqsoHNRFJr8e1L4D1/f4TeC5IJ2FdsBrd9SeUVoXBUKYIqoKD@2wh1jwXejxHNyJElHmErVUHnf/4@@9vFg@cEFk4KW2D0bQ8U4UuMNovC/WzVc/jGObiu00B6IPX2Tp@stDlo69zBmKGjks5bvj8528wJkfN@HhlILAJSyEUNGF9DKzMyE0gU0vcoVO5AvPR82IgvsZBSEbe71smBqwKaHj8gLqrKgHTBICC7MkIp0qs9es51JYxIsMn0eQrR9FV7y2QZj84@@irItOj1SI2rPl@TnD0ooM5sfitVTHiUbAejbJFzeJchCVmAwnOgJHbqDRrnivMWdo83ozNFGfVVtpGVFxfXl4xvQjptApGRVf615fLR6@/eP7dqXb/MYCEymSSfUezjf5B/25lcplNgOpT0mvlrsr6F70KkwuTuScLDqR4QcQc6USu4mp1ObimlVPA36Yw/XOHfPqKS@RhxQj0ClJmGJ/4FHjU4tN0yyqyK0CL2P6Wca26CjRBUvQEsc/jA7nqBJIQ4oT9pUNSVd0h1lbFTwJhvhUfA6ai4x2uaRgvnIvRzz0vq4a1VqTk1O8aDZavJW4vYiOJ9ofO@Oumc640ulMfqhUJ2BblAD8mUk75@jPr26LRqvy9Wtq3zBZnip1XvKh7V28PX19enR2fnj@7gxsnAoqC8dREtgLE0FKEPtwA8PI5@c94Efiuen3zcYTbjekJzmgqrKizRrMqjBYqCdzw5KzVdblomiKPm5J5n33OnPz0fdYburYKZd2LlglXTZz5ZkCEPOwJ0ewqzPkoTi3a8wVJ0dmTRCkgyAOPkd4/rSOsLu9HF4wfJ@ewfScjGUoTuoCaj0Q0SqAc7wFjEByLRHT/yXMY/iR72NOUN/DHMDS91ZfWvj48PVPqwsvrUkAK/1z3Vg6Wj@awG/DAva5btMBzkxjovwAbmYSYPGHoiqMWGJu1NJ5gZd0qE8m2ceupu3A09@UtjUjC2KwQz@FCe31YBMubzIyKbCloqY7L@zKBZBuzD1cmckSwabN1YMYmIwxwinnkxhc5HB85nTdWWbHNf/517@J88tOhva/5@0@2v8p2h9NYtDqgZfAcc4aYsv716cshZ8ShAf2ZIkmchXkirxwhGgnAAevOUMIXCC7oHcxj9p@D35CCGAm2Twyc3w9N@mqwyyL90yTPDuC077Bi2LuBHKAlTScKDB/GdFxMiyzub21vWmZQFK/nk3ITykGVKERE2raHvRHuvbi5qdLhzUaDSanSPHd5nZdMNIs2h9r8qc5okXASiIIaDOMwZDFCPS18mFq0S5ZGg2l/adYCuvW4d@FXOAiVN4AiEavw5wfMnxQlLOKDjzcScbN6c0suEFkEUYsID7xHxXMJtIxkZhbk6UV3QW@6OFlGO9OVGksi0H@QGC8aLMnr1MdBg35rzWaE6L9H6Ld7lT0b911B@Jz3TlcPfdW759aEy3s4CyMqDJ3DFyZWjWrNdPa1pb2iZxPBWxpV3zFlNgH2FeO632O4vTw5dHrH09Oz1bObTmkch9MYUqrUeroRrndnTeUezo/Y@mLY/PszYvjGSOXscq77mO1bvL7iD2w2AdR8lpdinesLGRVfuvEixR8LSGLBH0J8KXIzVdWVbXbabvbaHXCwsryX9f9qKJgbNDvKNDqpPwnFQpbY2DmRb3z6Arq8chpsZ4RhPdl@dzYy0fToWy1Zfbca5NOESXDnPXAN6qNO9hq4mRb8GC2POxE/qZoyVh3sZYjrRRalhERyW40x@TOyDmzieYTkdPxH4bYIcL5xHMEdMqNq8j8@K8YEPu/zhbpAlIQbCiPZ0U3PAPANp8XLnoer2nZyU1OwbznzA08/XyGD236xVEdjBCSWSQe6dD3Lut2sz1h84Osx07xjDT2vUyl47OJQZkVqFE1IsBq@C6dvjV2u/lRH5udyJX4od7pCPw6jWK2yGZfubPWWyQ07NUIk0MDXPbjKABcn9/eumThXfbnSMdg8FGZIdHGKmpOgxH0trC6MXQnPW8AL6FqZRiUHyxrcRxoayVkoQpsqGDVH6kas8yY33WEucQxu20bXthzJ6oyVrS9LnEH75Xxh2tFk1d0gJ@j5oeqvfsHqrO9b2f5JpwfRi5vnFnAgsXzoww4EfqZGx1gI0XwoNMHf3LDECqjAu0ACsLsEehMtPLst5bl@S9jluzCv@QnI/e9xJFy60fwhUWzzpOR@hQO4VOHdbJOvxOSV6jfmH8wDbN@qxb95o0JR6611OKwaZVqG6VSMdxQiyG5smfPKIeZFuEpLwzZkCcA0ou@Vgc/4VmbxbBetBtqsdesbvAReCyVtFsM@Jaaxm3RnprFZ3BMZbxJhHaoxVQjcVQMw5oCP5JQ0SwHdnyrykye0A@MaPmiVyoRDkbxghD4ZnbOStxMdc5MnjXV8wDJHAQzNb6jDL/@WrC2EaVP1ai0X609PdCZbG50Xl3Xlbbdrxq/dE@vTk//onVUpfDyRLY25fqGKRXMjcrX56b56dMnxAxMa@tKt622nj/fKNe3dzbKB3XFKh9YFcvS1GpVO2NPOpth/cmTJ6p1qihbNeXsIx2J7z/FP/6Hz/yRrk/5m/w1B1n9PNWY@stEKrSeQElq208PnnySClLholXCx@DXUmlv70DX9Qm@RmlfKnxqAKbRnU5LjXbDaLX0bqstFW6lwmQqFaoykb4hFZqTxls@uv0qn6b0y0@4NPRuOz796ejw7KhcbeiF6vHhy3L17N2LgoWnrcUjddbo8e3R4auTd@flqhj1x9fvj96d4r3neXHa66W9aNhtHRyUDCB4YLS6QGbyQ6lVamZZxn6@2DDsRCq8ak3emXoDCPwkFd5yWL2jAfqrVGgX2up@db9a8SvXFevKunoTnSz@Tk7w3ptUPkdJZVgZWr2Dk@2TTcuyJhX3XeWmcjOpBNGJ1UPTxb9KgKZX6U8qg0pYCS3rzmQP/wUn0ZuTCFNFGJZNKhnNWunjPjg5eYPJ@lj9M/55lQohOalc46/iW/zz8aKiVSQkgd2t7bi6/UubG5Wt3W7bnXhZV2ZlpdNWuvWCmXY6ptBiuQpFpO7p9OLi1eH54cWFSbnRpFEsHZT0A3yarVIjv@0Xei1imyEpKvK0uKPARdh1Xksq0oFr2@qWirf23mhKFohtWBsatx5blXp94zBvb6KdN3fqdTe1HY5BXREoqaoLd6fKVmdS7bOqzL3ILvawVWs01O0trdXa3sLj9o6mqxXq3NQ@WvOuqhYlsjKRo0Rht1PxT72dNlT@0eifptHL/NrSbtUGQACzpfFnMQBg4w8fPtD3w/h6LFq8Id59mHcuP/AGPtcPjF1tID@Ev2VKYVoggxyyzS0N4b2rbW6rO6Xd/F/zqQbs5ZpSA/ayIs2E1bQKRKxUMOpvZauKHgivTjWqyHcNHzF0bVeS8ZGal@7AC6VG61aCu7lECDFmzysIJ3w6jI36/aeS7YkuuE7kHEi4U9f3KXmjyHEcJX5vjGiG4JBHJ8ym395jW6Wpi09warsj1x2PRmN3/nnppXv25892TLYO3q8iGeSpqtXdna2d3Vp1p7yzu7O5ZW1vbZWtatl6vvN8t1KGvduxtne2dq3yzuZubXNzcxe9W7vPpYIb9ry@acK2WDAydO@5fSrRjXaYXNvpVOT5m5ilCHCivhIrurU/2pG3n8t7cu05IBCW0W8QGvRrjcgYtphEP7xhKiwwY7e0bdRYq08x/wzt@cIM2m8YDF9dl6hfOANVfg5NVeoAq68MSa72kLImFDdzaISV27syvQaImIBtW1JhKvXonHFzt06mdNpoSUWFEFNqUkGvRZtRoVgswuyet@SafGJITRoO2RZkGltIv0Zb1rfwx3phL1Zqm0qt0yyIHWU91wqt6nMjtW8KXfGOqZt42S3wfVi1ChabeP9Xf1HK@mP@mW@TlU2z1FrzPL4OQN/OH3qDgVf9w6evSByYorDqFmPWNhIK85veEH8NXF6eCLLl7S1Zg3qm6ceLjxd/qULtdne3C79i8COpBnrnkVLfRRAxCtaFSoeJ98am2k44D5fQeDNCTD1XMEYaRkHosHX3Hde6O6/4f4zAO4nwIqGr1IBNdcq84MQ2uH3taux2VqZUqZcqZdq8sJa42SgJWaUuCqA0hVefN7EKbQnWJABeDYMZVb2mVWdegybDHQFVvgJ9ZiNKTWpSIM@x8LpaXVquGHJMWhi9hMvS@FJJgE8FWoIeJ@gJskXf/BHoBXSy4qj5aO0eQLvSBYzSqSg5mb@FDETM6nyGMvvdZNwbj9hRm9HEUVh05u8XophKG1k5qEtE9kZcl/6kOtotxbT1b8GzZ87HuB1061rQzOheKgX1qXSlegJkI2sGTd2qx0C2nrVLJa/bDLQ/qTFHPmhWAIy1aeZUu51LOmzm4kq18pd2qH8Lu@XjdliyuuVReePn5pey3ayUJ/iCbWW//AuYN2OlmjW/lMK63cCXwus7nIibacmu3y3kYsiV6je/tO1us6LVfQwslY5BDPBM236p1NWwuI/O1YF1/9kzu@S3JnVf1zWC@ljbP25naHRLTXreU@3GZP9Le4TxeyruTSzja0Ae4@7KAPMBvzp4LMS3QF3gOCH0JkAvaDY3ft7f@Hmj@fTpl/ZED7plwf69ykLwhPyEkF/WEXXj52XF4izhJy2q/IO394OxkTK5DO0Dk8vx0kiB4cbP6IkXu2H6Pw)

- Reng can be tested to output 19 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/).
- Modular SNUSP can be tested to output 31 [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/snusp/snusp-js.html).
- Surface can be tested to output 66 [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).
- Japt was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Incident was tested via manual balancing of tokens.
- Surface was [tested locally](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip).
- Moorhens 2.0 and Deadfish were [tested by WheatWizard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37986357#37986357).
- Morse was tested using my [interpreter](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).

## Incident report

Somehow tokenized `#1`, un-tokenized it by adding a `#1` before the Morse.

Never mind, golfed by WheatWizard, added a `1` before the `xi`'s.

Answer (score 6):

## 107. [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 3303 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOx4O6O@MoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zinge -'";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ ppppppp            (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002696 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3396 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc9tIkuCzEfcP5qUEsg2ABECCFCV@S2pbnnF329JZdnevSVoGQVCEBQJsAJQoy3TMvexOz23c7c3OTcz27k3vTNxFTMTd015cxG7sRGzE7ev@iv4D1/@gL7MKX/yS5Nk7WgQKVVmZWZlZWVkfhPu6P/rhhwx@yLFrX53ZbkAC0w/IwLMuTE8lH1@Rfd3yK6Uyx1Eozx1MDcs5I8HIJJYzmQZkaNmmzxl6QNpkEmJRMUEyxDP1AQPjhq5HsAoZn9vEIsZkQvq2PlINYlsA@6hYJebYfWORt1CeIb47RujA9CaeCVefOKY5IP7ENKyhZVCqxJwFpuNbruOrxDLOyaVl22Rg2lAhYcWQARmZ@qksRljlBi5H4GNMlhiPn7ImwDhm1Hhzonu08S6ZUElEMrj09MkEmOQy5AQYD6yx6RMrEHxi6r6FEoUqvukMqNwmsaxdojvpVpILSyc68Dv1KG7f9AJonkrxkpHpmYBSR@Jnnj4m4qVnBSACFOsBOTZ1jzz3TFMCKqAO0zf0CfCxQBKIuUghwIaoVG3NpnB49EgA9bEaqj4JuIxXfv5vP@F0orZI9rQB3xbPN7jDpw/JdbaLaeACkIGKJ56oS6T1nviFbteE70zrF868OQdYOZCKTQruJCjoygQYVAJgsKBjElPKRUmd2CnCpLmki5RRMagBaIM8dsjnMm2ZMfU8E/hIhKqfQ6Nt1zkDeUJjvamD8nDIThFUYLjOwJeJeQFScx2mI/eSSvj5yAKl@agSvQ8C0g2UPesQVKDQJcD2QolGdH3XnlI4qOkHaIAgFaiKGB8PyedkqFs2VoFyRMW49kx/agdYZ@oMUPNjyzEHKonYMNwBAo3dCyCnA1KaAX1onOp5lCkABkW4tKlY9N1f/PXg7AzwHBiG6w1Cc/2cDFxjOgaGdcqsDqaIBus6uk3ZAjgZqbPqQOBCt62BHiB55yokQZmgVC/dqT0gLhD0Li3oWiP9ArrjcGgagcmM3J0GwKNMxvo58xcWs1xo@Fjvg2IpAUqbNlsh@w9AS4bJTEYZT4NhlSiTQyL4hVfiXl3c2@qawJukSrlsoXDWAHtTczQLnoSbDOfzg0SfaD3PLRf7kT0ZTcFrQInjT8CfeChMQ4fm@OhWAvCBMulTQVNfBKZOO@mlKXgm6UPPjhpGbYTZANZXsOeGGBKdRnCLJmYOUhYG1glGFvgrbsJ2L4Ew5Q0dKdi0g8T1Mx1IBWGDDliDGEWas9i0cwcsHbH1TVJV@hZoB@0AnE2ojFQbAbxcYjCAjWkv1SnG@hVgMZiTTjRJrCEoeQx2610Rw8TOAL3CZJ4OiUypYfgW2JE7JEWlVKncovzAKxwoL8F7vC3cqGNs/JKaD8jQvCS27pxN9TMwZNeBKrphmJMg7EHQEj@APrLsCGmmEnp11R9x2f1l2tS7hf4@RQO9D9Ne6KN1NHsQ1BhErdjQy4nundGeSAaWB/3FvlqmDgAXS8T51wiywMBrfgML0dAERmbOTGMaQHcDQ74cWcYIbBe5c1iHZd5xmTxkpamDy1GGMWlkRmvfL3FqIc5CNjaiUFCjq3jA6yOq9kIGVX4642bMuj9eg9iNWQQPlcpVC7oKthcKDcbzE4wlwP1FgzftWXGAEcsTBAxdHbopGMsoCCZ@HdyNFYymfRXUWnjuXT0OjhzUbCHwrqzAZem@7fYLY92HzlSIKBSMad@aLbWI5sUCf@NzFzCMD33SAv//1RRMRBSGviA1aP4DBE4V8XRopSjYlQdACqSCpMShr2II9gg8wMmVY4i8Su1ehR7Cy4THXsZLkMBasVweuGN0GeQLOrxgvPCxB25mCK6Fm1wFI5CDYhBeb7kT0xGFBaMUJEpQlBo0OhAE9Y1rOeK1sLW1JdSFtiBDag9STUztYSoPqT2aUmgK4VRM0RoyTWFph9bAvJ4w70SYZ1IP1TbDEOitNRH1Tr1e7sl6RwvvJbxL4JfADQG0gjfAI0itFiYliW9fQkPV/pC1/hmT7IBawzPTOePM2cT1AvL06OHh6fHB85@0@MLU9wq21S84MCCejqG7QQjMr6kPsWxUHZLPXDdoUYVhPoV@nI5wh547jr2Dz5nGyCV8tsxjZIahsYIOZYxx2@QqKt3G0qlj6@P@QMd8ivY5OKDPIAIin1k4MA0X6HCxwLoczxRaXnQtfFJSYsHbBZgyuMnJ1fpBlU@johWAzXMX@1CSOi2qWmUBBUwFVmsOLX9ELwugK2ytltDa/rg/pJc1APVwVIQhFicNKJdPMOTEgdl1YYJxScHGruMyVkBelqMXntGbCs50HT@LPmuBmb45nEIYWuhbDqZvAVNqVQo57PetTaAgF2Q9uq8B86b9dWIDFzZaGdbIguCDqRfY5iC8/8tPB6CAVfWM9Csf4tvzOHEKckNVKcON2gqr4gO9rNfsm6kNs59bcBg6xrS6HSfW48KOSRRlpHugzatIm2CNeAEne5u9Q1expwMzuq8nQmW6OFqy2o41ppqEOw791JtuqL401rP6OCfwbFcfUCxsrmaZiXqZIsyZfgaNK6Tmj6rXvwOf0ZBMkskZDGfBlF1xPnabIq0Jfm/qoCFksaL3NbPg@nrf2iBFZGJnkyGz/oHDjzK09XOWPMXk@qayxnjWGUz@ovsmMAiIIGad6IZZuKS3jT7FmfoTpgpM3YDPs9l1E4jlGBD6OkliEyA006aXDzE7aggG9A1kFddDlJSIrCWh2nr/Cofo0YfbDxI8y@eJAv6kZeTzxTJR3GS6kqy8TCab6xtGWL9WW1@bLdJQBIYLM0vztj4LA4011m2lNEglN/rcKKRJUutckn6hQ7Bj6z4YSBCK2bwAtdDLTUaLY4cxtXUvSd1gsgk70ax008QmqTOxDNe2QsuMHjb5wuUoM0GDy2/0klTFp1X5DiCww3FZiVPrO7RrBDi52GBHd3BPLK7HmVPKMFR3k@wM9xK/G3vvyL0w2XX9GPV2LVd3cD@KTS0DJgur1QfGbeaK6yb0sl6K52u5Cgx7bX6dPHFdDyZ2PimpRYxoHLrYByO0bbO5y/PHR5tt2rds1ycn9HqTLCAC9X12XW/NabFZuqMYI9bH4vT6amuZosMbOaDXDcrV7TPX3qmeFXS4bLSAqTdELx/e7@rhYg@labd6qDi@cR0tvG907efwd5tx4IIB@HILA504ud5QNrqzcFqzuYEwD8AFovWNe1Ssxpbl@eaNJsVU4RmjS/0quv8R48gmOUfjyOSKxskQ12GFWhUSgcdi5z@G2vbN1AZ381YraHdva0RKzee2Cb6bXleUS0pF7QNraMXi3X3X0J6aU3OtLznqvzHBgG5S@d2ZKobNyIYz4AIID/d4Yqi34SzwTlzjyI5PN7oe3bagu98a16x1OhOItSc4dT6GxDEmViueOdPJgnJTsns2dZ7dLLnRJOrj7mCBSSz5UN9UvT16WgjIfZN@17uSOjkcuzDXdccQTTh30H@IlK5OsOsCYpqTYH5jPYBQxLsRb53EK1oQyUJkAlq1zn0FQp@NY8Ci4yltmqRT4FoNZmWOGVzhdZO017nUvuvaH6Id8KwDCwM2CENxs/M2LdXJydW4DzGckSy33UED0YQRpIWT442KPQaUwR1xlleXm24Yr1KLT2sp/9i12832TWTDhTO6TxcvnPtyuMEIeZYXbif58Z5t5rFjeCZdRo9WakkGF/enYwi1A9dTCYUTRT2flySOVcJo7cwBsAiK7prhxgXbkPMJxNABhbWGpNMh2etZvVjX5qRF@DpPej2GlS6hH84mdLvrGavayeq9VlZQFCErdJ06KQoU1LRh8FwLqi/ADS16Y3wmTSeOPqZ7JZiOWtpgGzIQ0@Iu3Eh3BrZJXoAN0Ejf9di2Atu7eo6rOf/8@0G4OXlmQiPHlg8u8szBDXV3bI7cyz1GN6R@MJnouLmJOGA@a7MdDeXBAfEvrcAYsT1JCLlfPHpeDTeUwq1@eDjGzpbigikVzQ940AOmNMbNwDWZWYSE41pRo2BSMx075NIaBCNfhQDVMUy6YRUvk0IKwZzAc9GsZPKYDEycXA@QsTdT0K3tuud0ORY5@effs200KLTQhDAdkaf7uimKBAYUje5dGYY7Ba4jJG9Nzw1BRBQyTM2m6K3AqE2WLxFjpNP9PbBEJdrdQjJsh@vBwQlRDomA5xJwGb5hDcXswbMff94p9lrvybhg/stPC9J1KDf@I2VX83mZRCCNOdpVurgIxUmpQPjsjA@bhTvgdMM3NirWm4iIaaquaLdqTDfPqd2Zl3S3im5JOujIcFfa8aF/wKNEUbNO08qKU9saWwFRTgJSwcMbJogEUmy7neBxCNx5wSrZGXlHRmgrikG0ShGemEBs3Owbtz6O1kLL6TXrwkOzP6VrORcltVRu0eZkT1vgVzDlmQMXt4M7r7qXvYIfSaXbnX1ULM1AbK4H4PcL2HMOnz68zqrt4rt3PgSpPD8XGmwpHbp39vr48fHhyfOD5y9OQIxz1srMI9cb64mLQCOY2DCRGLk23V8HeXiW6d/uNu5Rv8HdCwFFkWR10oSwjYCHuhc7llCsvMJnWZKVUU8Sly0Vhu5jaJHQ1ZFjqu1QsYKfdnNyZAAoPOiTU/CrEfNgONdr3BVtDk9a0CAFGkTBY4bjp3UNWyyl8Ezge/gMQg@bkYaiTU2g1gNhWxlwyDeDYUyubcT8/xHnExhHbuccoW7jHIC526inCD86ePzZi2eHq7RTZEOYFZDYQlJHmg5nEKaAHxxSC8dt88hu3PDYQ@QYwO@P2OaobieuzScXlm/1bZNa0hAdsw19GzsFXVH1sXMT9CMqObB9cKSDAXiG/lWAjgU8qkr3sdhmluIQPgMCUONxTiY8h7B@a3X7GxzHJYRZxmtWOUvhKGZ/3QmSrln47i/@mp0a6QaQ/jpMDyH95yz9qoACWj1mwHiMRYNi@fzxMfFhtGINH@uzVJtwwMAByXJgemWNQYIXVCAIzphN2pvgETufgzxBCSBM9Hzo7Cg90@uJuO9cLxRwfD9z7aFKN17MGegBfCXdhv5qiod4wD8Xdio721oBmFQuIoSKxRAqE4ZQkupgQtyFNWm97huk2WwS3odw22ztNJggC1n9VZl/HTOaBViOhQIdAnWgSlIDytphNTGr5zUJq2IvFDSB9BowyjO9wEAh0gSASJjthPLgYSRyQ1GB0h1zFlCnehWFOBBfOC4Zo5zoUa4IkQKIGG6J51ZsN1ngx83OlDWraTXwXyDYCYLV@XWm03lFukHX6YVnjggYzN@uMSQH0j9fcxAptp6D1fNG4vJpIWwN2T9xXNzyeQTcErFUKJUL2o6U6il8iAr4xX7xDlBCT4CeZZjWG3fiHzw4fPzJ0fHJynkZCiksgwlEaDfzXUWVO704ISxZfSTUjx8VTp58/CgSZZqrZMaEEMm0aZnNddSWOd1A/Qu2u7JKmxasENKKd0VM51zKI7qysIo9KS2kAB@w1d8VqqJ0Pe/0mu2uk1kh/27d6baMmkPjglTXp2fbBLLG5zyO9oyeu@dgL2p0BKDEJ0c3DY5OPt3wOcnefIomQGzW2/Rhn2h3Ck/SlNqFgXlRcKa2zanJvhWfFZsLLZN4kIBaYATpYRLGXsQ1eJyIYQ0ZTsga3MoOQJonErYoJp2uGesIRXXE5oj0YJ/uwPTAg8k0hfapm2YzSXoKDeYSj4Nk@gFTGpwZ01nWFZ1RgMOIV9QHFt150b3o1EVccmKOLeV5xA@6j@R8DLgzPPcxgrbZVr@htzozEp@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@BSPzJDn60YIcHyvNUAoZxuJPwpMTwGhmwR0fCte2C1FNttCgk8vGHEb/110c/odhAHBV@FFBLTSuxazduipASCa1xeyopeXLuXw@6@TErINByf37OCedZyHmOVV5lZ8BkJK1pQbYM8RIrazTyOpNMTtolXK0Bjzm89I1VHjvF9TrrD4vZO9DTCFDjsd6p5j1JewORVXV5sAf9pBsQQabuRZ5ws/wgC6Sz1r5PPKgZk@RgfeF7kmeji7dkwKdBTfCULdwNo7cyIJafvgho@3ArGtvpyy6e6XyVi5DMvt8Idd9@PLlg4uG0NGHJfWr3vH58fGXUlcUMg@OeG2bb5BcgcsUcsV3u4XC69evIQgknbbaVntSRxF6HbG9u5tryDvVnLwva4LcyBBbK2qaJJZK0kl3V9dz@e3SvtOwLGviDwbwdUcQ80IoVEcF3YOPqB0LQqUsnLzCQ4N7W/CP/sEnfsTrFs0JsynI6mdLIuJXMy7TvgdGVd7Z2r8HDJt5@qnX9@lkgN@t8q67z2Xec5krLvO6@ZrLQPCbabd783le6ah56Id5Jd/sNJtquz1rK712h8tcc5nZnMuUeJRajsu0Zs1nFG/nYZsRyH8F6D@De1PpdSbHnx0enBzKpaaSKT06eCCXTl58nNHgqZI8YmEZH58dHjw8evFcLrFaP378@eGLY8j3e@39/byqKMq@2u4BF7OP8u18KwgC8vI0Bz3nYXv2oqA0gehnXOYZhVS6wEZXAvh3XKaT6Yh7pb1S0S5eFLVz7fyJewR/s@2jnaN9ln5ydASl1qz4xvWKo@JIG2iaNiuaL4pXxatZceweaQNImvCvOIakVRzOimdFp@hoWojhtr/xkfvkyAVULlQLZsUAsRaHcD87OnoCyIZA@A38s4pF5HJWvIC/oq3Rz6tTmDwXu12uQ/jXJlihqglqUVB3BMHqVXYmX13PSztfdeggUan1OubMCno8kYVup1arCb1GpuB3uwXWMfgSWDVCzOenpw8Pnh@cnhZw4jxrZvP7eWUfPq12vhne9jKDNgpVbW51OUG8/OKLL/D7xeXFJUvRBMv7Ii5MP9AEfC421F1MkPUfUexUetdzSZLudYWGwFoiiiYEPiKvdWelISnxNJ6ogTfRyjhm7VSkdnunAs87VUkRi1i6Lb3Sms2wqCS5Hi/MeNcTyPWc/ROv502RfiT8J0mYGV7bkgjFUgWeZtfirCk2RcyDLKx1PW9jksJdQ6ojSj1pPmd5cBWlJsPZlqClOPf7//Tn@sSfECEzz@Ag4pDtigQzS1Pa3hGr@Vr4r7UFjRH5slCGNvKCLnQ6@7lybne7s9fL9XJiM6fmuu3eLP2RhAwBI4yspqVlUHpcRm0847USL6AVNXA91bVN1YZ5XrnWEMQc@5Bc/KlqtXwuv9/J1WqMWi73bkuC6oCch08GLI2IpNluxupPLEFqw/eahAKG9PwaLIKVwRgkhgul3e6sWKTwjX4re53R5w2Knsz5CDo0LIpeFBp0BZ2/5rO619F6/JzPXvfnOFbnNImOsZXtRiO3zdK71QaMDFouLClCSZiEAtPXDdrDYDBASxJAxBI0qtU3zywHxucF085XKpVCCa6zj3YOSzOugSvNbFmbV3hm6aRaowgzxPdrHISDfVD0JdktQrhv27pH3OFwi@VDXEv6pgmhhWnbuEaDYR9EP/bgEqYaW1wGPAIEPVAMn/Gxbk5N83I6vTTjzwPLr@tv3sCshX6@//bXfwrf38P3F@z@i/9Rq@D1@2//03/77je/hcx/hO8/wPfvv//2r37KvvT5D/D9p1TeH8JvCo59OcD177//9pe/@/7bP/8Gvv8l/H6z/P3uV3/H/v53@A@Tv/3uV3/AC3sAXL/@@Xd/9TNg8VeY/jNIw1@Y/XWYTOWy5NdREur9zRLwz7//9i9/F6Z/lgZJ5UPVryH/N6n8rzkOlblFKrtRQuOe4IpPTWP7XxZmQ8oza9xPQKPjqTHCbUUrwLAD5gNFTkX9l0q1aqVaK5eqcrVW3a5oO5WKrJVkbbe6WyvKEHFUtZ1qpabJ1e1aeXt7uyYTrVSp7UJ86AysYaEAA7bG84QmYNqJJ4CbeHbaVUdtLjMwhxB03yMzcSDdywyiDDKtEr5c7RZhokvnBSKRyDWOMyLxYXoInItFeQrutbI3rfI7u3w9B3d@jy9Dkpr3TCRFAXoiL3R5XurUenv8boWvQ6SjCPe1PcLv1mDCsLvLSw2@wvM7pLTL8y8teiZG4BtzYDiSRNwUAuORqhL4KgqH5ZMW40bkayKh9l3r8qz3s64kiIKwWxIESWgAki0@3QGlBjYNWsYaFnHGg1CBsxqMKw3PDKaeI9YUcJ1EqUmNOWPp36R48s5hbqJ7OD@gJOuE36nxmA0gTbGGpNqVfq4ua4q8z7F@vaNxmTk3wEOO2zXSqDUwzIKxptnmsgKyJZS5jFJ2t91MNpuFMO15my/zR2qzEEZc7QINt7oYgWHso0ahXJsUOM/EjZwB/rKVDZjVCrbljPiZ/B/5UYFCC3ByDXTUfGbChoYrjCm7jKHm@ww9f0KOr@PNgalDlxvqT1DSev2EHv/u9Ij0/qllX1fLSptOk2CuPCcg2/lJ7dXuq@qrJy@OXhw92i/Wq/UqeO@M/05yK9p755NGpj4RyttCGQK9VoY1TtuVMu3SrurrV5leuN0sbu9KBJ6oby5pmSFGIknAshKopFJrni8vxjTSBUaqPxqcnVmlHz15/S5bKAgCIVp2573SZH9NuDw4YioW@Z0KL@E2vf/q9NVpBjww4UsVMMF8gYQ@diHUmeUc@s/M@fSfaSYZPjxGT1huSjmYsH1ZAv9Qq@1UdzLcD4XCTetrUBpPNYcmTMGm43VzzQPPeqLjPNyJ55uQeDJ9a3qx@yDoP3AJBR1IOi/0Kaks@sNsyOOQL9rbMKF7Z4ZMN15IDn8z0OmBc4k27UQsxX0jKd5mYr2QFBtsOxBRWI04CVTQCcCsv8gycV4pWi2tQawmIoM7TEdDCviJauRbmMRlKMqF1ZMaXHr/jHLShtopXlL183kGPmdssfYY4wFrNiuLH4G9MZ4zMMSwtrQE0Cn2cHmjWxTCZt6lGYYeiDEGmXxwM5bqw8xbitpEWUgKw/xEFXMuF8jjBofNzk0a3KeiIV3jikDj/fj@fePVpDPuNaRxK8B7Pj8G13kuWgwkF7TGLUVrTIDZRtDJ561eayx9Kk4o8@NWEYCBNmL2petY004rVJcvyW87jvLe6cmPOk5e68lTOfey9VbWW0V5Bl8Qm2zLX4HwIlGKQett3mnoTfji4sSCJGAYyeuNxW1NqHIu2q23Hb3XKkoNGyrm84@gMcCn37Hz@Z4ExG0oXK3YsO/f1/N2e9awFUVCqFflvUedABK9fAuf66LenO297Uyhfl2EewvI2BIwD/UWdQD4gL8GyJipL2Gd8ThD9mbA3rjVyr3cy73Mtba23nZmyrgnM/HXi4nikfkZMp@2ETH3Mm1YVCQ0nBb5j6z6R2rOJ7wM1gdCliepmozD3EsomSS9YY6uiP5KPFr4wuXQcD@T/TCQ/niLrmPjWx/wlIaLeXiwAuoe@IZlheDsRMzEMgd4ht7yZQiAHUWnEFgWvkcBC7uzvT0uIh1utgFlPMrSN4mO51noj5Y9DO7pOzl8w7Pw/RA3O7F1vi52bFHAdPL45SGB4Ky8k3J2EnfN3aN@wfeMDoJgH78uzhvcPQRiW6wtkAmuFwMMBG8yRaXAnQpJQlDoCwyyFRZiMBYqCGqR/nQ4ZGcR8bd/Pjoa6MhRZ9WgN4VsQGdew4Ylv0Ervof2ZEEKHA6lxzwOdw8agTxgG6weaYOjJffvk/Cx2YKAcxegKBjCvclrCLTCKRC/A6eAA7l8AzYKTDIiwNs9LMGTAQuEtv91hMLTNSJUyL@R2SEbtfQlL@MCs88OlaHcJMYG6uLevTf51nbIEPzR0BHqQ9n8h0w4ktbJg6Mnxy@eHz57cnACV620XeUyeDrFd61BPX6FwspvsSf4G@u@5dBtcEN/ppl/8okBoQGEVWBS7gBf2TEgn7z4DCYGTx/KeKwaRI@HlMDAbd@tx5hMn/5O1Vdd76xwaZ1bhcOFc5BQie24@3X6zgJ6Mt/BNzjgvBHf0hEfdUtOuvk4ZdEH0VnQhbe9jE3fD39irkQvfaEvtqGH/sZ4dg16YfiTdLqNEb1JgK7747xWprtJnnVm0Td5jBiChfr0J98Bq077B4c/JR/ogY4WzdWqxWKdFGVMaFGiFCXKUWI7SlSixE6U2I0S1ShRCxNahFljmLVStVzeSZK7SbKaJGtxcruYJBMM26UkWU6S20mykiQTatsxtZ0qxUsykTRp14VwDcq07WpUhkdVnYBmVgCNtpy5DYyWViCh@vZKJtCrLmbCVDQk9LhwhECl0k7yDN4ngm2JjCuZ8SEzyuwpzISximPTCGqwh54HXulwhi@6AKOT6gSPInEcuF1i2KYOwYAZQJTSegT2b0p1dqTVu6rHg5SJGFpa/AzVTZitQR0NrSg0nzXFpXXFDFtpLTZ2JpjEgkkFYSGTjMv64ikrinF7IS@NdQsdLEp0A0SJQaAOEi7tFM3n3nQtyfLNJBcQriW5whTDW1lXC2UjUuStqCod/ym2VkSPxSkm1TaEAeEro6gNLCkUzza3rrU6//233/x38v23v/wt@e43v/0/f/8fMf13ePmfELOQUgzwi1/i5W/w8p/x8hu8/CpVicKX6/x33/wtPP6H/0q@@9NfsqK//B0vb8eIoASzkpq//jO8/Awv/4uXKzHgr3/OALEKL8@5hdBKBKhf/CMhQA2xxMi@@T0hfB4CDDG0vA7r4z1JWkIQi6FDU73lcnY1Rh6KvSjlIbjPh09a8pRHBUgp5J6O70BK@h6EM2zzH720oRsjPG4XZrk@xj8GhjCur56BvV0OIOgJ5@UCtP7fkToR8ggD2fRId4v58LD9Ybv5pBRh83wBuIPnCBWmpZgT/8rnwL7pTODKV3HWI1EbYjYSyvcpvmMtGkD4yLKsQIRpUEgrqt3ReiR8MRD8RXVkarQ4DLEj0fSVUVx4ckxLEVxwN0tqAyrLOXmSOKOFqjTDHE9AJVAtljcKFh@oFORldInmwm5zePRoqcPgpw8h5nnaI8WEWoTnb4FFSYfwEkZc5UV4xm8I0CnWyz0ufYR0HTD/5Zdf8lwqr4g25A1EiiHVKOYy4iJtsaiUKiqlioBnhpP6mkqptMQDHTjQL0rLh2YXXdRitcS4sOdEekA2YC7I1tvkoT31R61V1NQjLzq7VeQplFqvFfaTrkN9Tpvw0koFwLlYp7Wsy/Woiyswq4paXxOlvZCzoK3NmBbqpDoFlR63LKVYc1ptneYWCd6AWuvl70ioVPxXElLuSGincjuhZbVi3QX0m@V7u9uJ3ETs4RNkrONnFgYoHBq/AdNL3BFy7NGkKMGU5yCc8vQvXSKueakU5Bei31UtvEnKS/3aCicxT93AZMsD@xMXphwuRsGpFxm@CMEXph3svYFnjuuZfvost8VOxDkC/k7AcM8cGNVk/H2XFb7TDH/dwn62tTiuxCNbGIU@YO9GRNRMUBh5np5ajhWcnkLwaQ@lRID4qBq4jidw@FJFSKXqi3FoezQRXfxdaiDdjpPGu6zac8s4F48mYaEARA4ITOgM04bJFxnpxjm@HpSKBJtIT1ZjRNoPRAmFOHLH7pnpuPgbCay9hP5xghsZ0icTyotMdJkYKY7CSbRoyLoUVv30g6uST0uiLsX1S4sIFoQhE29ZxihZbw25043kWLWI3smH83uS5vfkZn6HlucHyzzTTFztwfuHkS6LCQYATNgo386GHP50aYWdBVbibHxZG6twZxYHpm/A8IecHgDoQQiuDsE@5PjJh6eY8c83yf9mBUbVD@@qPhrMnlyBvxkfYuxHp2g@/eGmY5gigD@W0PeskotN@@EdaYUTHTrDkwlPHZeDp92gY04mpuPHm48R4lts3jobrdgQzUTbx/sanrwLmZyXNqvo4enAtPUrcyCGkHIKb9TiZ6Y@oP7qbg1HR0ednsve0CcWZW0hFKOnkilQfYPJ6PKFJG02KwZixdZD97koh483y48u3C27ZlwEbbGtGtcDD5qhvwmkv8ScXE2u2O8ZbPZe2dCPsvGHafIp/szjVoGAHOiytqjJCVnpJvf5TIybdIcRIYZVF5uMh5UjjHhceFWHHyai21tKVxniSq1IywvRySaNWzdpPGUVkU2yqORuJnmb0d3Z5lKmxpAlLuzBhw0hK5gf6LZtGGIaI8u5UWOus@ITMA815jobRpXTNQ41rkk9XYBv2Gqx@ELiLEg@hvsF3D@HOyKEOegpM6iobRjXRktetGSsT1JRS5jTMTAWTUlRSu8jpqC4KI0LufOYprGRprFC01igGfeARZIpIM5YIBlqAdVzkwpscxhs8M5YhDN3uN3ktuHjuLqHe8LXgiXULZkIF0IdHLJgCvVDEZyyMBDqD2nCF@onNHEu1D@FRNK3hHdCPeoWCODBI03sY37owvHZEOoPRGnO0beJR3RVoR7rFGD22COVyJwtr0LUSJdC3HhV1TRlFlTKBC3Gh5uLzer0ZPotwh8FDX9oD4VbLVLKUWCcgCwMGqkRg9GBYUOlL4cW1w0f9WhpKlzfSNZQoDzfSi2qoJVMqT8SMsKiM2KMYSldfIT7Fm66O0J9PUdEW5mZ3cZOSB0slCq5vrTnDtJTaTwwEGl5B4DTizh2Uj/S1yIKpsC78YmVN/G5wk5EjnKEpwakNWyhUF8LNzQKdb3IS6j9tIZW1whQiUoEwrRE0aZ8OsRwGJtSYhN3smgktBR3@6x0HfyEnRKtd6ka9Qphz9xQTLPDlqFjSHd@6abmpOohawsuCAs7xR7rZfG4QH0xFiW@LhWpss4HLKR8zoD@1MtEs30YJikcczcyHSs2DUNRXUaSeq5FNwmVVTxmPdUDRj3Zl8HD1x82fY1qQggOPCKCVM2YCvOv7gfE7y6L36OAOhLCEoF1gfX6oXQ1vL5xlF3i3E7IrioQC2XyUFobHMUUEpHD7CAVmd9kayshPr5ylQX5jGiMfSnaj8QWzwlukdvy3ILhwijBu1jMPMeF2fPSZkGtRiT2hRoFLSpSCvGwhsecJk27mVfW8HUqxhIco@H2wQr2FhWcVh7iow3wlkTOejm@wJzuU8R9Ozp2Fu5csF0HF0@xxa9TSGWCu6e/NAx3K2TMODp99vDo6Wd/AoPu7u6utLoVgb0W6ibjOHfjNkE8bSnJ@FNX@r9y4NmJkesFW12HX/ElzFlDMKDTfRtmfmEfl0JflvLnS30X6jHYlERDXOdJN9AXvBKGOjoO2VYo1wAEYgZiTg@RROEtyFumszXcNULrwA2d01M6fJ2e4uGc09NwFEPVxNtI/xc)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically, 97 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>, 107 [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)

### Explanation

This is another addition from [A Brief History of 2D Programming Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829). Gol><> is derivative of ><>.
They can be distinguished using `@` command, which rotates 3 top elements of the stack in different directions in ><> and Gol><> :

http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish#Stack_manipulation

```
><>:     @ - shift top 3 elements right  1,2,3 -> 3,1,2
                                             ^top     ^top
```

https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki/Differences-to-Fish

```
Gol><>:  @ - shift top 3 elements left   1,2,3 -> 2,3,1
                                             ^top     ^top
```

So if we have stack like this: 107, 4, 2, then `@` will bring to the top the number we need:

```
7aa*+42@n;
```

I use `2` because of Whirl. Also I moved Alice (`/"78"oo@`) closer to top, where it is less likely to cause problems.

Comment: Cubically should be available on TIO, but the interpreter on the repository is more up to date.

Answer (score 6):

## 108. Ruby 1.8.7, 3340 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)S\7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding:utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@
#~
#y
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.+..]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOx4O6O@MoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"arY\"[2]==89and 2-93or 4"))^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;'(******* **********819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!)'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57
set ! 51
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"5""6 27""Zinge -'";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end!"            );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
#<<<#>>> /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78"\++++>/<~#class P{        function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"  +/ ppppppp            (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002651 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3433 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIkthzI/wP9qUEchoACYAEKUr8ljTd6t2emW7Jre6Z2SbZahAERbRAgAOAEtVqdqxf7nbWF/Z5b72xN3feud2wIzbCfjqHI85xG@EI3@v9ivkDnn8wzqzCF78k9Z7NFoFCVVZmVmZWVtYH0X3dH/3wQwY/5Ni1r85sNyCB6Qdk4FkXpqeSj6/Ivm75lVKZ4yiU5w6mhuWckWBkEsuZTAMytGzT5ww9IG0yCbGomCAZ4pn6gIFxQ9cjWIWMz21iEWMyIX1bH6kGsS2AfVSsEnPsvrHIWyjPEN8dI3RgehPPhKtPHNMcEH9iGtbQMihVYs4C0/Et1/FVYhnn5NKybTIwbaiQsGLIgIxM/VQWI6xyA5cj8DEmS4zHT1kTYBwzarw50T3aeJdMqCQiGVx6@mQCTHIZcgKMB9bY9IkVCD4xdd9CiUIV33QGVG6TWNYu0Z10K8mFpRMd@J16FLdvegE0T6V4ycj0TECpI/EzTx8T8dKzAhABivWAHJu6R557pikBFVCH6Rv6BPhYIAnEXKQQYENUqrZmUzg8eiSA@lgNVZ8EXMYrP//Xn3A6UVske9qAb4vnG9zh04fkOtvFNHAByEDFE0/UJdJ6T/xCt2vCd6b1C2fenAOsHEjFJgV3EhR0ZQIMKgEwWNAxiSnloqRO7BRh0lzSRcqoGNQAtEEeO@RzmbbMmHqeCXwkQtXPodG265yBPKGx3tRBeThkpwgqMFxn4MvEvACpuQ7TkXtJJfx8ZIHSfFSJ3gcB6QbKnnUIKlDoEmB7oUQjur5rTykc1PQDNECQClRFjI@H5HMy1C0bq0A5omJce6Y/tQOsM3UGqPmx5ZgDlURsGO4AgcbuBZDTASnNgD40TvU8yhQAgyJc2lQs@u4v/2ZwdgZ4DgzD9QahuX5OBq4xHQPDOmVWB1NEg3Ud3aZsAZyM1Fl1IHCh29ZAD5C8cxWSoExQqpfu1B4QFwh6lxZ0rZF@Ad1xODSNwGRG7k4D4FEmY/2c@QuLWS40fKz3QbGUAKVNm62Q/QegJcNkJqOMp8GwSpTJIRH8witxry7ubXVN4E1SpVy2UDhrgL2pOZoFT8JNhvP5QaJPtJ7nlov9yJ6MpuA1oMTxJ@BPPBSmoUNzfHQrAfhAmfSpoKkvAlOnnfTSFDyT9KFnRw2jNsJsAOsr2HNDDIlOI7hFEzMHKQsD6wQjC/wVN2G7l0CY8oaOFGzaQeL6mQ6kgrBBB6xBjCLNWWzauQOWjtj6JqkqfQu0g3YAziZURqqNAF4uMRjAxrSX6hRj/QqwGMxJJ5ok1hCUPAa79a6IYWJngF5hMk@HRKbUMHwL7MgdkqJSqlRuUX7gFQ6Ul@A93hZu1DE2fknNB2RoXhJbd86m@hkYsutAFd0wzEkQ9iBoiR9AH1l2hDRTCb266o@47P4yberdQn@fooHeh2kv9NE6mj0IagyiVmzo5UT3zmhPJAPLg/5iXy1TB4CLJeL8awRZYOA1v4GFaGgCIzNnpjENoLuBIV@OLGMEtovcOazDMu@4TB6y0tTB5SjDmDQyo7Xvlzi1EGchGxtRKKjRVTzg9RFVeyGDKj@dcTNm3R@vQezGLIKHSuWqBV0F2wuFBuP5CcYS4P6iwZv2rDjAiOUJAoauDt0UjGUUBBO/Du7GCkbTvgpqLTz3rh4HRw5qthB4V1bgsnTfdvuFse5DZypEFArGtG/NllpE82KBv/G5CxjGhz5pgf//agomIgpDX5AaNP8BAqeKeDq0UhTsygMgBVJBUuLQVzEEewQe4OTKMURepXavQg/hZcJjL@MlSGCtWC4P3DG6DPIFHV4wXvjYAzczBNfCTa6CEchBMQivt9yJ6YjCglEKEiUoSg0aHQiC@sa1HPFa2NraEupCW5AhtQepJqb2MJWH1B5NKTSFcCqmaA2ZprC0Q2tgXk@YdyLMM6mHapthCPTWmoh6p14v92S9o4X3Et4l8EvghgBawRvgEaRWC5OSxLcvoaFqf8ha/4xJdkCt4ZnpnHHmbOJ6AXl69PDw9Pjg@U9afGHqewXb6hccGBBPx9DdIATm19SHWDaqDslnrhu0qMIwn0I/Tke4Q88dx97B50xj5BI@W@YxMsPQWEGHMsa4bXIVlW5j6dSx9XF/oGM@RfscHNBnEAGRzywcmIYLdLhYYF2OZwotL7oWPikpseDtAkwZ3OTkav2gyqdR0QrA5rmLfShJnRZVrbKAAqYCqzWHlj@ilwXQFbZWS2htf9wf0ssagHo4KsIQi5MGlMsnGHLiwOy6MMG4pGBj13EZKyAvy9ELz@hNBWe6jp9Fn7XATN8cTiEMLfQtB9O3gCm1KoUc9vvWJlCQC7Ie3deAedP@OrGBCxutDGtkQfDB1AtscxDe//lnA1DAqnpG@pUP8e15nDgFuaGqlOFGbYVV8YFe1mv2zdSG2c8tOAwdY1rdjhPrcWHHJIoy0j3Q5lWkTbBGvICTvc3eoavY04EZ3dcToTJdHC1ZbccaU03CHYd@6k03VF8a61l9nBN4tqsPKBY2V7PMRL1MEeZMP4PGFVLzR9Xr34HPaEgmyeQMhrNgyq44H7tNkdYEvzd10BCyWNH7mllwfb1vbZAiMrGzyZBZ/8DhRxna@jlLnmJyfVNZYzzrDCZ/0X0TGAREELNOdMMsXNLbRp/iTP0JUwWmbsDn2ey6CcRyDAh9nSSxCRCaadPLh5gdNQQD@gayiushSkpE1pJQbb1/hUP06MPtBwme5fNEAX/SMvL5YpkobjJdSVZeJpPN9Q0jrF@rra/NFmkoAsOFmaV5W5@FgcYa67ZSGqSSG31uFNIkqXUuSb/QIdixdR8MJAjFbF6AWujlJqPFscOY2rqXpG4w2YSdaFa6aWKT1JlYhmtboWVGD5t84XKUmaDB5Td6Sari06p8BxDY4bisxKn1Hdo1ApxcbLCjO7gnFtfjzCllGKq7SXaGe4nfjb135F6Y7Lp@jHq7lqs7uB/FppYBk4XV6gPjNnPFdRN6WS/F87VcBYa9Nr9OnriuBxM7n5TUIkY0Dl3sgxHattnc5fnjo8027Vu265MTer1JFhCB@j67rrfmtNgs3VGMEetjcXp9tbVM0eGNHNDrBuXq9plr71TPCjpcNlrA1Builw/vd/VwsYfStFs9VBzfuI4W3je69nP4u804cMEAfLmFgU6cXG8oG91ZOK3Z3ECYB@AC0frGPSpWY8vyfPNGk2Kq8IzRpX4V3f@EcWSTnKNxZHJF42SI67BCrQqJwGOx859CbftmaoO7easVtLu3NSKl5nPbBN9NryvKJaWi9oE1tGLx7r5raE/NqbnWlxz135hgQDep/O5MFcNmZMMZcAGEh3s8MdTbcBZ4J65xZMenG12PblvQ3W@Na9Y6nQnE2hOcOh9D4hgTqxXPnOlkQbkp2T2bOs9ultxoEvVxd7DAJJZ8qG@q3h49LQTkvkm/611JnRyOXZjrumOIJpw76D9ESlcn2HUBMc1JML@xHkAo4t2It07iFS2IZCEyAa1a574Coc/GMWDR8ZQ2TdIpcK0GszLHDK7wukna61xq33XtD9EOeNaBhQEbhKG42Xmblurk5GrchxjOSJbb7qCBaMII0sLJ8UbFHgPK4I44y6vLTTeMV6nFp7WUf@za7Wb7FqU/w76rqVV19ybAcIWNbujFK@y@HO5EQp7lhftOfry5m3nsGJ5J19ujJV2SwV2A6Rhi8sD1VELhRFHP5yWJY5UwrDtzACyCottruMPBdu58AsF2QGGtIel0SPZ6Vi/WtTlpEb7Ok16PYaVr7YezCd0Xe8aqdrJ6r5UVFEXICl2nTooCBTVtGGXXguoLcEOL3hifSdOJo4/ppgqmo5Y22M4NBL@4XTfSnYFtkhdgLHRK4Hps/4Ftcj3HZZ9/@sMg3MU8M6GRY8sHX3rm4M67OzZH7uUeoxtSP5hMdNwFRRww8bXZ1ofy4ID4l1ZgjNjmJcTmLx49r4Y7T@GZAHg4xl6Z4oIpFe0UeNADpjTGzcA1mVmEhONaUaNg9jMdO@TSGgQjX4VI1jFMurMVr6dCCsGcwHPRrGTymAxMnIUPkLE3U9Ct7brndN0WOfmnP7D9Nii00IQwHZGnG8ApigStl25yGYY7Ba4jJG9Nzw1BRBQyzOGm6NbAqE2WLxFjpNONQLBEJdoGQzJsK@zBwQlRDomABxhwvb5hDcXswbMff94p9lrvybhg/vPPCtJ1KDf@I2VX83mZRCCNOdpVurgIxUmpQPjsjA@bhVvldGc4NirWm4iIaaquaFtrTHfZqd2Zl3Rbi@5dOujxcPva8aF/wKNEUbNO08qKU9saWwFRTgJSwVMeJogEUmxfnuC5CdyiwSrZGXlHRmgrikG0ShGemEBs3BUctz6OFk3L6cXtwkOzP6WLPhcltVRu0eZkT1vggDDlmQMX9407r7qXvYIfSaXbnX1ULM1AbK4H4PcL2HMOnz68zqrt4rt3PkSzPD8XGmzNHbp39vr48fHhyfOD5y9OQIxz1srMI9cb64mLQCOY2DDjGLk23YgHeXiW6d/uNu5Rv8HdCwFFkWR10oT4joCHuhc7llCsvMJnWZKVUU8Sly0Vhu5jaJHQ1ZFjqu1QsYKfdnNyZAAoPOiTU/CrEfNgONdr3BVtDk9a0CAFGkTBY4bjp3UNWyyl8Ezge/gMQg@bkYaiTU2g1gNhWxlwyDeDYUyubcT8/xHnExhHbuccoW7jHIC526inCD86ePzZi2eHq7RTZEOYFZDYQlJnnw5nEM@AHxxSC8f99chu3PB8ROQYwO@P2C6qbieuzScXlm/1bZNa0hAdsw19GzsFXXr1sXMT9CMqObB9cKSDAXiG/lWAjgU8qko3vNiul@IQPgMCUONxTiY8h7B@a3WfHBzHJcRjxmtWOUvhKGZ/3VGTrln47i//hh0v6QaQ/jpMDyH9Fyz9qoACWj2PwHiMRYNi@fzxMfFhtGINH@uzVJtwwMAByXJgHmaNQYIXVCAIzphN2pvgETufgzxBCSBM9Hzo7Cg90@uJuEFdLxRwfD9z7aFKd2jMGegBfCXdr/5qiqd9wD8Xdio721oBmFQuIoSKxRAqE4ZQkupgQtyFNWm97huk2WwS3oe43GztNJggC1n9VZl/HTOaBViOhQIdAnWgSlIDytphNTGr5zUJq2IvFDSB9BowyjO9wEAh0gSASJjthPLgYSRyQ1GB0h1zFlCnehWFOBBfOC4Zo5zoma8IkQKIGG6J51ZsN9kJwF3RlDWraTXwXyDYCYLV@XWm03lFukHX6YWHkwgYzN@tMSQH0r9Yc2Iptp6D1YNJ4vKxImwN2T9xXNwbegTcErFUKJUL2o6U6il8iAr4xX7xDlBCT4CeZZjWG3fiHzw4fPzJ0fHJysEaCiksgwlEaDfzXUWVO704ISxZfSTUjx8VTp58/CgSZZqrZGqFEMn8apnNddSWOd1A/Qu2DbNKmxasENKKd0VMJ2fKI7oEsYo9KS2kAB@wZeIVqqJ0Pe/0mu2uk1kh/27dMbiMmkPjglTXp4fgBLLG5zyONpeeu@dgL2p0VqDEJ2c8DY7OUt3wOcnefNwmQGzW2/SpoGgbC4/clNqFgXlRcKa2zanJBhefFZsLLZN4kIBaYATpqRPGXsQ1eJyIYQ0ZTsga3MpWQZonErYoJp2uGesIRXXE5oj0BKDuwPTAg1k3hfapm2YzSXpcDeYSj4Nk@gFTGpxC01nWFZ1RgMOIl94HFt2i0b3oeEZccmKOLeV5xA@6j@QgDbgzPCAygrbZVr@htzozEh/RuOmMjepPbCsQ8XDLTMWZGrRGlLABWtM28WxMs9YLD@KQ6LxMnh65OZ6CvI7dCUlmxw/NKPUMJkjk4RSQgzGY5JPpGOCG9PbMxLHCJE9dBSqDHIWIiQ5QEcM2qONBBairI3M2sM5gvBElGRzTR5qWHNbRpTzMagXwxkxUP8Y9hbRgPuiAUUpiekdXLWdgzkThUpDqPZQO5AuXX1wIEr9iA/SUU3jkabB83ClyGXoQ9t3kqNCSW6jVYnew2INqNXXkc3h6BmJ8oHgSeJ9BEkZScTjWJ0Sc0vNiPlEJfRS7oiP7gScRpY2j2iVxSD5PZwdwowUqoTWHNGXZeFxTxEO6YqEFesZc3xng7a01IR1NVXuQpkQkksWJ/QMIOnBKLHEQSkKVOkULwzD8qyNHlzAPQo7YPUvJcjgr9wBqbTHtyGcj2gFBFrTVpH2fJD4h6YFMqrVaPdTGolOsETCL1fFILQDaNc4uijtBvuGJCJAaujKAegDzPQscyv6npuNAfxXBZsbQO4k@BSPzJDn6dYMcnz/NUAoZxuJPwiMWwGhmwR0fCte2C1FNttCgk8vGHEb/110c/odhAHBV@FFBLTSuxazduipASCa1xeyopeXLuXw@6@TErINByf37OCedZyHmOVV5lZ8BkJK1pQbYM8RIrazTyOpNMTtolXK0Bjzm89I1VHjvF9TrrD4vZO9DTCFDjsd6p5j1JewORVXV5sAf9pBsQQabuRZ5ws/wJC@Sz1r5PPKgZk@RgfeF7kmeji7dkwKdBTfCULdwNo7cyIJafvgho@3ArGtvpyy6e6XyVi5DMvt8Idd9@PLlg4uG0NGHJfWr3vH58fGXUlcUMg@OeG2bb5BcgcsUcsV3u4XC69evIQgknbbaVntSRxF6HbG9u5tryDvVnLwva4LcyBBbK2qaJJZK0kl3V9dz@e3SvtOwLGviDwbwdUcQ80IoVEcF3YOPqB0LQqUsnLzC04V7W/CP/sEnfsTrFs0JsynI6mdLIuJXMy7TvgdGVd7Z2r8HDJt5@qnX9@lkgN@t8q67z2Xec5krLvO6@ZrLQPCbabd783le6ah56Id5Jd/sNJtquz1rK712h8tcc5nZnMuUeJRajsu0Zs1nFG/nYZsRyH8F6D@De1PpdSbHnx0enBzKpaaSKT06eCCXTl58nNHgqZI8YmEZH58dHjw8evFcLrFaP378@eGLY8j3e@39/byqKMq@2u4BF7OP8u18KwgC8vI0Bz3nYXv2oqA0gehnXOYZhVS6wEZXAvh3XKaT6Yh7pb1S0S5eFLVz7fyJewR/s@2jnaN9ln5ydASl1qz4xvWKo@JIG2iaNiuaL4pXxatZceweaQNImvCvOIakVRzOimdFp@hoWojhtr/xkfvkyAVULlQLZsUAsRaHcD87OnoCyIZA@A38s4pF5HJWvIC/oq3Rz6tTmDwXu12uQ/jXJlihqglqUVB3BMHqVXYmX13PSztfdeggUan1OubMCno8kYVup1arCb1GpuB3uwXWMfgSWDVCzOenpw8Pnh@cnhZw4jxrZvP7eWUfPq12vhne9jKDNgpVbW51OUG8/OKLL/D7xeXFJUvRBMv7Ii5MP9AEfC421F1MkPUfUexUetdzSZLudYWGwFoiiiYEPiKvdWelISnxNJ6ogTfRyjhm7VSkdnunAs87VUkRi1jKKnR53ftpl@@Ueq1WtYb5JaVWBsBtXpJeac1mWLckuR4vzHjXE8j1PPknXs@bIv1I@E@SMDO8tiURiqUKPM2uxVlTbIqYB1lY63rexiSFu4ZUR5R60nzO8uAqSk2Gsy2BOHCC@P/pz/WJPyFCZp7BkcYh2xUJpp@mtL0jVvO18F9rCxoj8mWhDG3kBV3odPZz5dzudmevl@vlxGZOzXXbvVn6IwkZApYamVZLy6AEuYzaeMZrJV5AU2vgoqtrm6oNk8FyrSGIOfYhufhT1Wr5XH6/k6vVGLVc7t2WBNUBOQ@fDJgjEUmz3YxtJDEXqQ3faxIKGNLzazAbVgYDlRiupna7s2KRwjf6rex1Rp83KHoy5yPo0PooelFo0GV2/prP6l5H6/FzPnvdn@OAntMkOhBXthuN3DZL71YbMHxoubCkCCVhEgpMXzdoN4QRAy1JABFL0KhW3zyzHBjEF@w/X6lUCiW4zj7aOSzNuAYuR7O1b17hWXcg1RpFmCG@X@MgZuyDoi/JbhHmBLate8QdDrdYPgS/pG@aEH@Yto0LORgbQohkDy5hPrLFZcBtQGQExfAZH@vm1DQvp9NLM/48sPy6/uYNTG3o5/tvf/Nn8P0DfH/J7r/8b7UKXr//9j/8l@9@@zvI/Ef4/k/4/sP33/71z9iXPv8Rvv8rlffH8JuCY18OcP3b77/91e@///YvvoHvfwq/3yx/v/v137O//x3@w@Tvvvv1H/HCHgDXb37x3V//HFj8Nab/HNLwF2Z/HSZTuSz5dZSEen@7BPyL77/9q9@H6Z@nQVL5UPVryP9tKv9rjkNlbpHKbpTQuCe4LFTT2CaZhdmQ8swa9xPQ6HhqjHDv0QowNoFJQ5FTUf@lUq1aqdbKpapcrVW3K9pOpSJrJVnbre7WijKEJVVtp1qpaXJ1u1be3t6uyUQrVWq7EEQ6A2tYKMCorvE8oQmYm@J54iaexHbVUZvLDMwhROb3yEwcSPcygyiDTKuEL1e7RZgN08mDSCRyjYORSHyYQwLnYlGegg@u7E2r/M4uX8/Bnd/jy5Ck5j0TSVGAnsgLXZ6XOrXeHr9b4esQDinCfW2P8Ls1mFXs7vJSg6/w/A4p7fL8S4uesBH4xhwYjiQRN4XAoKWqBL6KwmH5pMW4EfmaSKh917o86/2sKwmiIOyWBEESGoBki093QKmBTYOWsYZFnPEgVOCsBoNPwzODqeeINQVcJ1FqUmPOWPpXKZ68c5jA6B5OIijJOuF3ajxmA0hTrCGpdqWfq8uaIu9zrF/vaFxmzg3wyOR2jTRqDYzFYKxptrmsgGwJZS6jlN1tN5PNZiGWe97my/yR2iyEYVm7QGOyLoZpGCCpUbzXJgXOM3G3Z4C/k2WjarWCbTkjfib/J35UoNACnFwDHTWfmbCh4QoDzy5jqPk@Q0@zkOPreAdh6tA1ifoTlLReP6GHyTs9Ir1/atnX1bLSpnMpmFDPCch2flJ7tfuq@urJi6MXR4/2i/VqvQreO@O/k9yK9t75pJGpT4TytlCGaLCVYY3TdqVMu7Sr@vpVphfuSYvbuxKBJ@qbS1pmiOFKEtWsRDOp1Jrny4sxDYeBkeqPBmdnVulHT16/yxYKgkCIlt15rzTZXxMuD46YikV@p8JLuJfvvzp9dZoBD0z4UgVMMF8goY9diIdmOYf@M3M@/WeaSYYPj9ETlptSDmZ1X5bAP9RqO9WdDPdDoXDTIhyUxvPRoQnztOl43YT0wLOe6DhZd@JJKSSeTN@aXuw@CPoPXGdBB5LOC31KKov@zBvyOOSL9jZM6N6ZIdPdGZLDXyB0euBcop09EUtxc0mK96JYLyTFBtszRBRWI04CFXQCpIUA1Ogg6hOtltYgVhORwR3mrCEF/EQ18i1M4loV5cLqSQ0uvclGOWlD7RQvqfr5PAOfM7ZYe4zxgDWblcWPwN4YDyMYYlhbWgLoFHu4BtItCmEz79IMQw/EGINMPrgZS/Vhei5FbaIsJIVhfqKKOZcL5HGDw2bnJg3uU9GQrnHZoPF@fP@@8WrSGfca0rgV4D2fH4PrPBctBpILWuOWojUmwGwj6OTzVq81lj4VJ5T5casIwEAbMfvSdaxppxWqy5fktx1Hee/05EcdJ6/15Kmce9l6K@utojyDL4hNtuWvQHiRKMWg9TbvNPQmfHEFY0ESMIzk9cbi3idUORft1tuO3msVpYYNFfP5R9AY4NPv2Pl8TwLiNhSuVmzY9@/rebs9a9iKIiHUq/Leo04AiV6@hc91UW/O9t52plC/LsK9BWRsCZiHeos6AHzAXwNkzNSXsM54nCF7M2Bv3GrlXu7lXuZaW1tvOzNl3JOZ@OvFRPHI/AyZT9uImHuZNiwqEhpOi/xHVv0jNecTXgbrAyHLk1RNxmHuJZRMkt4wR1dEf3MerY7hmmm46cl@Zkh/CkYXu/EdEniUw8U8PH0BdQ98w7JCcHZsZmKZAzyRb/kyBMCOolMILAvfyoCF3dneHheRDnfkgDKed@mbRMdDL/Qn0B4G9/QNH77hWfi2iZud2DpfFzu2KGA6efzykEBwVt5JOTuJu@buUb/ge0YHQbCPXxfnDe4eArF92BbIBBeVAQaCN5miUuBOhSQhKPQFBtkKCzEYCxUEtUh/Ohyyk434S0IfHQ105KizatCbQjagM69hw5LfoBXfQ3uyIAUOh9JjHoe7B41AHrANVo@0wdGS@/dJ@NhsQcC5C1AUDOHe5DUEWuEUiN@BU8CBXL4BGwUmGRHg7R6W4PGBBULb/zJC4REcESrk38jsJI5a@pKXcRXaZyfPUG4SYwN1ce/em3xrO2QI/mjoCPWhbP5DJhxJ6@TB0ZPjF88Pnz05OIGrVtquchk8wuK71qAev5Bh5ZfdE/zFdt9y6F65oT/TzJ9@YkBoAGEVmJQ7wBeADMgnLz6DicHThzIe0gbR40kmMHDbd@sxJtOnv3r1Vdc7K1xa51bhcOFUJVRi2/J@nb4BgZ7zd/B9EDhvxHd@xOfhkuNwPk5Z9EF0snTh3TFj0/fDH6wr0Stk6Gty6MnAMR5wg14Y/sCd7nVE7yWgmwM4r5XplpNnnVn0vSAjhmChPv0BecCq0/7B4Q/TB3qgo0VztWqxWCdFGRNalChFiXKU2I4SlSixEyV2o0Q1StTChBZh1hhmrVQtl3eS5G6SrCbJWpzcLibJBMN2KUmWk@R2kqwkyYTadkxtp0rxkkwkTdp1IVyDMm27GpXheVYnoJkVQKMtZ24Do6UVSKi@vZIJ9KqLmTAVDQk9LhwhUKm0kzyD94lgWyLjSmZ8yIwyewozYazi2DSCGuyh54FXOpzhazPA6KQ6wfNKHAdulxi2qUMwYAYQpbQegf2bUp2de/Wu6vEgZSKGlhY/Q3UTZmtQR0MrCs1nTXFpXTHDVlqLjR0cJrFgUkFYyCTjsr54FIti3F7IS2PdQgeLEt0AUWIQqIOESztF87k3XUuyfDPJBYRrSa4wxfBW1tVC2YgUeSuqSsd/iq0V0WNxikm1DWFA@AIqagNLCsUD0K1rrc5//@03/5V8/@2vfke@@@3v/s8//HtM/z1e/jvELKQUA/zyV3j5W7z8R7z8Fi@/TlWi8OU6/903fweP/@4/k@/@7Fes6K9@z8vbMSIowayk5m/@HC8/x8v/4OVKDPibXzBArMLLc24htBIB6pf/SAhQQywxsm/@QAifhwBDDC2vw/p4T5KWEMRi6NBUb7mcXY2Rh2IvSnkI7vPhk5Y85VEBUgq5p@MblZK@B@EMOyGAXtrQjRGeyQuzXB/jHwNDGNdXz8DeLgcQ9ITzcgFa/29InQh5hIFseu67xXx42P6w3XxSirB5vgDcwXOECtNSzIl/5XNg33QmcOWrOOuRqA0xGwnl@xTf2BYNIHxkWVYgwjQopBXV7mg9Er5mCP6iOjI1WhyG2Llp@gIqLjxepqUILribJbUBleWcPEmc0UJVmmGOJ6ASqBbLGwWLD1QK8jK6RHNhtzk8erTUYfDThxDzPO2RYkItwvO3wKKkQ3gJI67yIjzjNwToFOvlHpc@Z7oOmP/yyy95LpVXRBvyBiLFkGoUcxlxkbZYVEoVlVJFwDPDSX1NpVRa4oEOHOgXpeWTtYsuarFaYlzYcyI9IBswF2TrbfLQnvqj1ipq6pEXnd0q8hRKrdcK@0nXoT6nTXhppQLgXKzTWtbletTFFZhVRa2vidJeyFnQ1mZMC3VSnYJKj1uWUqw5rbZOc4sEb0Ct9fJ3JFQq/gsJKXcktFO5ndCyWrHuAvrN8r3d7URuIvbwCTLW8TMLAxQOjd@A6SXuCDn2aFKUYMpzEE55@pcuEde8ogryC9GvtBbeS@WlfruFk5inbmCy5YH9iQtTDhej4NRrEV@E4AvTDvYWwjPH9Uw/feDbYsfmHAF/TGC4Zw6MajL@WswK35CGP4Fhv@1aHFfikS2MQh@wNy0iaiYojDxPTy3HCk5PIfi0h1IiQHxUDVzHEzh8RSOkUvXFOLQ9mogu/so1kG7HSeNdVu25ZZyLR5OwUAAiBwQmdIZpw@SLjHTjHF82SkWCTaTHrzEi7QeihEIcuWP3zHRc/CEF1l5C/zjBjQzpkwnlRSa6TIwUR@EkWjRkXQqrfvrBVcmnJVGX4vqlRQQLwpCJtyxjlKy3htzpRnKsWkTv5MP5PUnze3Izv0PL84Nlnmkmrvbg/cNIl8UEAwAmbJRvZ0MOf9@0ws4CK3E2vvqNVbgziwPTN2D4Q04PAPQgBFeHYB9y/OTDU8z455vkf7MCo@qHd1UfDWZPrsDfjA8x9qNTNJ/@utMxTBHAH0voe1bJxab98I60wokOneHJhKeOy8EjcdAxJxPT8ePNxwjxLTZvnY1WbIhmou3jfQ1P3oVMzkubVfTwdGDa@pU5EENIOYU3avEzUx9Qf3W3hqOjo07PZe/7E4uythCK0aPLFKi@wWR0@UKSNpsVA7Fi66H7XJTDx5vlRxfull0zLoK22FaN64EHzdAfDtKfa06uJlfsRw82e0tt6EfZ@MM0@RR/C3KrQEAOdFlb1OSErHST@3wmxk26w4gQw6qLTcYTzRFGPFO8qsMPE9HtLaWrDHGlVqTlhehkk8atmzSesorIJllUcjeTvM3o7mxzKVNjyBIX9uDDhpAVzA902zYMMY2R5dyoMddZ8QmYhxpznQ2jyukahxrXpJ4uwPd1tVh8IXEWJB/D/QLun8MdEcIc9JQZVNQ2jGujJS9aMtYnqaglzOkYGIumpCil9xFTUFyUxoXceUzT2EjTWKFpLNCMe8AiyRQQZyyQDLWA6rlJBbY5DDZ4ZyzCmTvcbnLb8HFc3cM94WvBEuqWTIQLoQ4OWTCF@qEITlkYCPWHNOEL9ROaOBfqn0Ii6VvCO6EedQsE8OCRJvYxP3Th@GwI9QeiNOfou8kjuqpQj3UKMHvskUpkzpZXIWqkSyFuvKpqmjILKmWCFuPDzcVmdXoy/Rbhj4KGv8aHwq0WKeUoME5AFgaN1IjB6MCwodJXTYvrho96tDQVrm8kayhQnm@lFlXQSqbUHwkZYdEZMcawlC4@wn0LN90dob6eI6KtzMxuYyekDhZKlVxf2nMH6ak0HhiItLwDwOlFHDupH@lrEQVT4N34xMqb@FxhJyJHOcJTA9IatlCor4UbGoW6XuQl1H5aQ6trBKhEJQJhWqJoUz4dYjiMTSmxiTtZNBJairt9VroOfsJOida7VI16hbBnbiim2WHL0DGkO790U3NS9ZC1BReEhZ1ij/WyeFygvhiLEl@XilRZ5wMWUj5nQH8PZqLZPgyTFI65G5mOFZuGoaguI0k916KbhMoqHq2e6gGjnuzL4IHrD5u@RjUhBAceEUGqZkyF@Vf3A@J3l8XvUUAdCWGJwLrAev1Quhpe3zjKLnFuJ2RXFYiFMnkorQ2OYgqJyGF2kIrMb7K1lRAfX@DKgnxGNMa@FO1HYovnBLfIbXluwXBhlOBdLGae48LseWmzoFYjEvtCjYIWFSmFeFjDY06Tpt3MK2v4OhVjCY7RcPtgBXuLCk4rD/HRBnhLIme9HF@HTvcp4r4dHTsLdy7YroOLp9jidy6kMsHd058jhrsVMmYcnT57ePT0s5/CoLu7uyutbkVgr4W6yTjO3bhNEE9bSjL@Hpb@Hx94dmLkesFW1@FXfAlz1hAM6HTfhplf2Mel0Jel/PlS34V6DDYl0RDXedIN9AWvhKGOjkO2Fco1AIGYgZjTQyRReAvylulsDXeN0DpwQ@f0lA5fp6d4OOf0NBzFUDXxNtL/BQ)

Languages not available on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR, 90 [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon, 94 [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically, 97 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck, 102 [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck, 104 [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>, 107 [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7, 108 installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

### Explanation

I used [this](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS) document to find relevant differences between new and old versions of ruby.  I found a couple of dead ends but ended up with the following

> `String#[]`: Indexing a String with an integer returns a single character String instead of an integer.

This allows us to separate the two languages like so

```
"X"[0]=="X"
```

This will return `true` in 1.9 or later and `false` in 1.8.7 or earlier.  We can use this boolean to separate the two versions of ruby.

```
"X"[0]=="X"and 13or 108
```

Ok, now we just put that where the 13 is and we're done right? No not even close.  See the 13 in the ruby line is not for ruby, changing it doesn't actually have any impact on Ruby.  It seems to be there for Python.  Ruby parses the whole first block as 9 evaluating the expression `9-4^8`.  I don't know if this is some sort of emergent behavior or the work of a genius, but I'm about to make it a hell of a lot worse.  So we'll change the `4` instead.  Since `100^8 == 108` we want our `4` to become either `4`, or `-91`, depending on the ruby version.  So now we have

```
"X"[0]==88and-91or 4
```

Ok now both Rubies work, and its time to do cleanup.

#### Whirl

Whirl doesn't like the addition of the `0` and the `1` and since I don't want to really deal with whirl I'll get rid of them.  Now our code reads:

```
"XXX"[2]==88and 2-93or 4
```

#### Perl 5

Perl 5 didn't like the `"XXX"[2]` part of the syntax.  So I used an `eval` to mask the syntax.

```
eval("\"XXX\"[2]==88and 2-93or 4")
```

This also saves us a pair of parens required to satiate python.

#### Trigger

Trigger tokenized a couple of things, in particular `XX` and `88`, this was fixed by changing our string from `XXX` to `YoY` and the `88` to `89`.

#### The flaks

These changes added an extra `([])` inside of the Brain-Flak code.  To counteract this I added an additional `{}` to our pop-chain.  However it seems that 2 were required, I can't figure out why, but I can't argue with results.

#### Incident

It wouldn't be a proper addition if I didn't break incident.  It seems that, through a complex chain of actions, `ar` was tokenized.  To break it I changed the two irrelevant characters in the indexed string to `ar`.

### Going Forward

Now that I have rvm up an running I can add more versions of Ruby pretty easily.  I'm going to see how many of these I can add.

Comment: Instead of placing ar in the ruby code you could change the one in the bash code as I said in the dash answer

Comment: @Potato44 I prefer this method because now there is no way for the `ar` token to come back.  Probably not significant in the grand scheme of things but It gives me a little satisfaction to know I killed a token.

Comment: Symbolic Bf works in this answer.

Comment: @SnoringFrog Did you mean to comment on my other answer?  You already checked this one for me.

Comment: Nope, just forgot I'd already mentioned that it worked in chat lol

Answer (score 6):

## 115. xEec, 3753 bytes

*(2 bytes shorter than the last!)*

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#xxxxxxxxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#xxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[        _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # 
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"1015""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3             #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002467 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3850 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tb3bkuvKkhj2vBD@g3nBYvfeJJsXALyzb2vx2iSb92uT3b17g7iQIEEADYDXtfvE@EXSjBW2PBpPjI7kOZoJOWIi7Cc5HCGHJsIR0qu@4vyAzx8cZxUAXrrZa609ktlNoFCVlZWVlZWVVZUoDllj/Mc/nqAPWVfl9UhWTdIUDJPkdWkh6EEyvSY/s5IRDYUJAkGl9NF8JiimcU6ckAwpKZzEwyNpqlNBkTaCDtEhUtPVkc7OSHPMmqRgcKwmGKQ6N7W5Sari8VxhMjdTJ1IAZZxJygigTEHXdMHEyRGyo8jsbMizrxKih6VpOiQbZFaQf5n9YpKcOpuxCm8AYIzM1tK5cupV/jhZUXVDQFg4wTBUFJcg/9O/W@UE7gDUYkBdV/k5h@gzxwKkoyqJkiwYBAelX5OazcYgCpAnpC6wvAVGiKpOoizkbCqTEslpGjmU2XGQI2UJYPN0ghQQC8gNpJ@QhjoT9gkwSEUQeNLQBE4SJQ6XSgorU1AMSVWMIClxU3IpyTLJCzJk2JHC@QEZOTf2oqyCgwSvEiR8OO0V4dunUwFgFMGpvKCxOq68ihgGnHB4sNRZTQMigXstINyUZtDkkuk2SIE1JCRSkMUQFB7zTdsKm0qyyn4tyYXEkizQO9cxbkPQTaheEOMlx4IuAEp22@aepS6ZwALE1hRZF1idbOuC4D0UvYMioTAVlWCiigRxs11eunO1vBuaz8oRZDWTONHD7UaJYMngFXn6dAHfK5frgshVs@SX0wcUtoQNmljTPayXvPoNaVAPDwJ8V8yQGukvBGAlgCsySamaSbEBDQgMmEAgxaIgCgUWoaAm7xVMXr5qiz2hsqB4aA2yqJBdP64ZN9d11Jt2TGWnUGlZVUbAT6isPlcQPxQyRkMTcCr0Bz8pLIBrqmK1kbrEHG6PJWg0AzUJOwQGsRzivaURMENBJ4Ds2Rx1yjVUeY7hIKdhIgEErkBWhLEokl1SZCUZZYF0hMqiWheMuWyiPHOFRy0PnV7gg6RDBqfyCGimLqA4FpDiCOhDs72eh4kCYGgIFVcVJf3@X/xrfjQCPCmOU3XeFtcuyasc1l0sJha0AokEVlVYGZMFcH5UupUdCliwssSzJipeWdtFYCJwqUt1LvOkCgXqSwm61phdQHcURYEzBUvILYXnJ2fs1NIXkiW5UPEZO4SGxQXgsnG1A@TnDLQSJ1giE5jNTTFBBrQc6Taonzyfzj2fPj4IQJs36D07pajRBchb8AxHwZP7a4LTTe3aE0lPW1JRP5K18Ry0BqQohgb6REfM5FiojoHUigmDgJ8cYkZjXQSijjvpUnDrAjmEnu1UDMuIJQMofwD1XBvDrk0duEMRE/g9CQPpBCEzjTdqQlaXUDCmDSlSkGkFFc6OWCjKtCuUsipklYhjDqs2VUDSEbahQCYCQwlaB8kBKBu7MfbqCODhkAUD2KzW2@sUM3YNWDhLSe9akpREaOQZyK2@JjkBdQboFYKl6VAhcywYBgyAaCikA6Fo9BuNb@pUKjAA7bGhvtrGqPKvmjlFisKSlFllNGdHaAxWIAvLcYJm2j0IamKY0EdeK0IcGbC1etAYE6efX5eNtZut7/fKQNrHaj1bR7NI7O2BOCBDLydZ24ogeUmH/iKvX5cOAItXhbt@RiAHBPzseocEZ2gCIRNWAjc3obuBIC/HEjcG2UXUKVaHtbTj6@Ihar90UDkBcVs0Ioa5/jFEBKltFCLjXRQB1KJv8YDWR6iuDyJw4@9HfB0za8yOIFa3JIKG2osNUmwQZM9mGoznLWRLgPpzBm/cs7YGxpafwGDo6tBNQVjGpqkZ56BuJHM8HwahWam2vi6aNQW1LGXqa8lUrfBQVofUjDWgM1FOCRQ3H0qrVzXCcVuGTwxiAcO4aJBXoP@f5yAiHrdouL0XOD6DgPeSXHhoxSisqwsAMVAQOOURjSAywfKgAVprhfO4gljug9BDXH7ShXqZywsBlGvLl4w6QyqD7OHhBdkLaR3UjAiqhdDW5hj4EOBIF3ulaoLicR8IpduLC/R4L7B14HYHJ6qkeL64P3786D53X7v9EPoEoUsU@oRCPgh9wqEADiG4IArhHH4cQqn3OAeKe3S/3DuYV95H1GwrZAJtJM3D3p@fhx/97D1j30Po7gW9BGoIoAPoBnjc3qsrFPR6XddLqGhwKFq1b1qc5bE0NAVlRAgrTdVNslrL5p7qqXbhykXNDZ2SpSGlwID4NIPuBiaw60h@sGWd7BBsqqp5hRsMxWPoPADZ1jphqnPooGC@SjPJLGKjWVaQaO8azUnNQLkWguK@iSzq6myrXgxC4MYq6ToNu5BpdzC9CGprJzWCUuf27GIvPo7iZ2hyEOSIEceRAdV63EbagAkEiOYLQbDpiZHPhyDx/GEbiSk9Mv@wMcQQBl4dCvIqFgkIshg0V5sg6nSxCGHdyAD/HsSRvMRqcywDYUIPCqzEVwmsM7tpg9oug91IliUDT9X2mUtsxeyBcFndIHyokF27lJBl8i5AAcDgoq2PmyKufVQ4A7TNVEWaZxd6ooNM9AAFTKDe5hQlY4wvB6BvyHqbgnMbs6GIL0cAzm1bAgwTNNVCfCkhQx2ZM6oK07IlBpupimqRAvySFJZq4lsQhqBj9Bxq@gNihoI4B@OdGkoKCn8DLJBMYEhxOJTeAwW@INKd@xEwfT48xjaQsPEbY4A8YLw5101Z4O37f/lTHhrgbfOM2bUBs4LpNvAEfENNFRDfbS07K3rAl@Mti2Emc1liMRtw6FsoORZNDFh5GziOGmk3MhAYszo07tppXBBOdIGR6lviDz1HnvOCcz9eCGbxoclh5VakGa4R3JH9hIekd7K/Mpis/Ghipcsqy2Ms1oRXEnatbbWLsGJHUDlqTy0F9eF30OnYNeRuhgs2gTm3rmhS@612lTT0/Vp/tSHpKDtkBEo12KH0DhcREbH35NrqLmgMD4gyO7WCTyh4vKpWZXRpBDNo5/4eGFiVYPhrLCdQS3x7V8Uoc0OzmgKFvoJPl63reyDOAto28B4gVFPGl18jdlgQOOgbiFS0qBTYY5H0iqkyO1wjO2f86@UHFYgHS1AvV5zPR4fRuLmd8@2WrzTt/fxoWMb5k8njua2VLoyAU2F6Lnyrz8K4I81YORDi94LvqmDHLtyFjoBO2AULFqPMGiAgps1mYQHNgi9fE1o0lHBzmdV3oa@I7I4cZ2r/3uxwl0eTOFWWbMl0Ht7Tha9N9R0atIaJL7us6Oktf3mwjtEwHdiGjndolTPRDO0dOfoO9WRNjtD0c08wgup7vOPUJfq@23vH6kKwrseHrM1Rqr5D/QRkLBkw43qbnee@Ja5o8QlfjnNxepQqk5OPxp@TFVXVYXZskKEgjQwcBa@YwoAty9YEsF2svS/ThiSrBtnC16/xAqxww7Cux6V5n20SqwS4sdXHtuHj2Y4ShYc3MoWv7zQuK49UOZYYUSxc3pWAuS4iLW/fv1fDbTUUw3xTQ23NHVVh7Pu7qn0K/98SDrTqArpcQobONvgVK@qYOrPnhu9XEKYFaJXteOXydALnDFLW1Om9BtC58ZJdO/d/xOjxHned0UNbY2MZrDmUIZmAgKlbBvQ/prTI10vjv09HvUEb/1Yl9hp3KgugsfH1TZOSIZr5lTkYmv5@jSXKc2EuHNUgteFEALH5mu74fqJouxqn9uIBBcxD22NbqI09FfwuqtF4jp6@qnBYWYJO/k1r5qiq0cDC1tD8uQ6BOgq8zThS5tpB4@7xrjlXml/n3FhzerbKHxCJUn6tRkp822Y6MMMNAX@PK5BztIELE151BjaE8h3tbyPF6zLW9QAxjtlhnkhoyUf/Kt5zcrsYCPYr2CPQqtLUCKB1o@9TPKH3ZuoYOJmEuZgimGt0fY/bxxTpUFXlX9M6oE95CZlpYHyifeJvtdI52VrPhmC5cbuVyu9oAWeaCNxCU@J3G7YOKM3vxBl@u9D2lVFqb9ntaMk3qnx9ef2NRm@ivssEE8H4VwGdNS/KCbzTBTGyZDD8PeaP5ti0eFESLWRaS5e7/eyTV@pFWwNjJD5gcGNhJuDHrxj0LD@ZG87tXaCVir5HkoMUXoZ8k2Ct0@Jt4e0@jeG397MhTtLt3Utj6yJwUlQ4XcC7Ns7GAHmC9pLmM5iUmKoeJDGcx8P6fF4vYWVCdu1IATAHCm/Son0ya//XIGG2YWJYSSTv78nTL6tz@px5Ia9I17mLfHy0sOIdm9xKw7urTSvr/Sn7eHXqDgTcp@4H5Zyk3RhUkMHMOArKHsCJEr5ZdO6qTirsDG/NobBT0wtr/w@sf7TpO2YVXhbIDvQbPCdSdWsXy9oqbaNlsP/897y9Fz4SoJIzyYBhZaQg/w11JozV5SerXLv0lKaxaC8d4YCZv2xtoAUyKdJYSiZICt4Ch8lJJ99O2PuXtmcJPNSRgtqjwmpU1GWBBta0Gs2ihlcFS6jtgre5nErB9G8@U8ilxJtjIwimvMIJeH90u6gOIQSmmLqKOoWfLJK8gJYheEQYllNZVad49R9R8p//3tq1hUQJiRAKO8VjN4K9EknU9/BWKcepc6DaQbIRdNUG8SAmwyR2jjQ8dEnBiveS3JjF28kgiQFnMxUVY22oZlItMpAj3cgNBu36XEii5zTVvOne049XvyFnlPBf/pTyfrH55vohEGcMl590QC5ekFztJ9OQvEt1k67TlcuuFnK4wP4FW6GynZ88KIyby9kcnWFfDSx3whJvjuIdcAUpf@QEoRjQP@DRi1Fbnebq1DO39E2gZZJR5CskAEsgZHl3kMj7Bm30oSynK/IXcoxkJcCRTJSGJ4shMtpbnl2lnUXk8P5iP5UVhnO86rUIBUPhK1yd06cr0MUopAu8irwP7n96WD5ShsOVh4fVD3RoBWxTdQD/kUI9J1fNfjkNXtO//GKAYe9yvbgvrF0P6N6nX@rFeq7VTrU7LWDji1XLk7yqz9idikBCoMkw5RqrMnbnAH7okmB8W218wHqD@GADejzkKUtegqlLgob6sFUsNltdAdepFbTSsCbZpr1KtNWHKJG2qiPruLXthnUb@2rO7wgAYh70yTnoVYd4EJwvR9QVro6LvIIKBaBCGHxL8PbpWMUOUzG8xfBP6BmYbldjHwpXdQd1HAjV1QK26bZgLCKPVuLlvxHlGowj36YcQX2LcgAmvlX6XsH5VLHcaebelr1XrA3zBmQrIXsedLkVmHagB0Us4chLw5Eb1faycRQD6P2xtRfPyjvVZpALyZCGsoAlSUSKWYa@jToFXns2UOcmkR4JkinZAEXK86AZhmsTKRbQqEG85WjtOwYU0nUCDAhuxzk/6SIQrHH11tsCFMcSTFPuZyvzKYbDmI1jDksPAvX7f/GvLSelBxPCf2aHRQj/cyv8E4UY9NarxaJxyxrElm6xThowWlkVn7GrvTqhAQMNSJICU1JpBhxcYIYgcIvYXX13eDz3XeAnNAIwE2k@pOxweYL@6EFuDucUhcb3kSqLQbxjJaygHUBXYq@H5znyGQP9TMWisQhDAZGBhYMwIFkIA5qF0Os9BxEiFpJ29fOQIy8vL0mXAVMU4Sp2YTGSOmV/Crt@3hJ6CrCEZQrck5AHsuxyQNq1nc1zyvoYL8qKeqGbcZOPFzDKW@0CA4UHBwDEi6IVmx8uGIlUm1XQ6IqwMrFSXTsmDtgXCt7tFizPQQdRABBZuL0u4o3s7rZC0C7xnjQH95vB1UNgLQR27jomOvc/kQ/mg/Jou7iRIDD/9oggKRD@8yN@b1vpSb11b/O8dk5DtSE/txQVbY7lgVrSE6JCYYqJefd6istGBfSifvELoISeAD2LE6SJqhmpTK5YqtVbb9yzMKT7NZibdF9f@h4CQf/94zbgfiX1DlPTeapVSecdVu5TtZtlIojdVPM1mcdKe03pO6X3rH2ot2XjhDcFMfT3Isbz1EAer8a8xb5LpfYAM9Y6@ZtSPd4vL/ePl9cPysmb4n855kx5EjxDwgWhBwO7UrrJIzqn6OyutZGfuhF0vDVCrp2n8NYzxHreRb/vtLX1et@5bjn7eMhxK3QN08kFpcxlmQi@s8MHdQ9SVlHYa8kizKEXdI1DKoNI3RXIEW92SfapIe26vHXQt51dtkyqWbND7EHKKjAx0CXOgjawgrbmkNjdEWYRRXM38YDJDFpHwPOrNZ5LgKrY7jrwEt6dYnXHC2eb0hJmUqDt0IMUx84RCxQZcjAaQ91kaXjBXt2vyK2zytd8tIKGJkumBzlHrYJojga18XhRBZhLWUC@VZfJR9uRi3T8rXzYZas@B37VVY3czYuzghNqwtSIzM4BOYiBQJbmM4AT8a0poFFCIKtqADIDH90OEfdQiseuQ3DGR6H04FhY8dIIRhqP1w8q6QeG2Tl7sV4fzGfdoIctVt2g7ZR9xvwqB7U9jrH3bFBSeGHlcS/d3vNHxB2Idy97C7fX9UYGsJec7TLHv3aXc5QFa9q9dudq9kohJJNbRXDYd5LJ4NggkB8RWPdQYsvUyxCEMdQjzliN9Myxv6FBBkn86HnwKH7D1L1k4BqNZ0tSIX0@PC@AG04IkjiniEOSjNZpPMjJ20NdQTujWEPh0W0jaeQ9Eww@QhgX4iVP0ZQ@A@YGmgx7CTAiIcs5RgsDMPydI4qWMANCFFn3U1wsgebjOkAdTcYdeTTGHRB4gWtNXv9I7rTBrgdaXE0mz@3WOFSHSRLE4vKIxgC0R9ScY3ECf21nEOAaUmIAlYGZngQK5fOtoCjQXz0gMzPonSQ7ByHTvX7n9SD/1n/5BJdwYpFYsL1LgNCTA0Wcc3@RVbBnTqkLPK28eIFx/@cHNPCL9tC/pv6EClIXXzyn8tWaAmPMe@05HV8xvvCZz3eqnHlOFWSO/Pgjmo2@nIK18xR0BV0rAAqcyt4LkGewjq5OlYtT9tJzyl@FznAOePT5vF8gw28MKvjllH2hTn8Ea8IPMbrVOz2nhhd1BzoYZF6APtRDTik/yMwXj4t0rZAnOCr@VPL5EA3B0ydEwG@oh5YPjysPLQrPfy9sI5cazRw1cmirbFvizRtLFgPt6POtRo9iV0FrnfHJAUZei86S6pG0Y/bRH/94wsRgpvcpFvaon0Lhj2cn5MlnF3Xm0l1fHrKLC/c9K4aCz4/1ab1@533wuE8yNRcTcUFtfrogzyjihDqjf4lT1M8//wzWJ3l/HbwOPnrvA@7He8/qOh4/u/DHEmf@z37G7b84IWWGZhivJxTyUuRDi3yIs@yZLxL6rFxIkqQZPA9fdYzesABL7ApJyQf4eJi62x0Nu1s/IRfZT58@wh/@h8/2EV0/4hg7GoO8/Xz0kp7nFXFy/WH1j/lQDBN6QDO2cOzj5w9QZcGHP@fnn/E8hnTFEy5V/YxgyfEJw0RJ9WSXPYA@xMlviJMNpDEna/hj0Cd78mSDESc/X/5MnICxf3J9/fjy4gvcB3/yBYNPj76A7/L@8jJ4fb26Djxe3zsz2yeSOPlCnKxeiJOQC1rv4Yw4uVpdNjFh99lri0Lfsw1ehvBl4PFeq5dzqVbOH7oMnITyqYw/1OqkTxh4iu4eUWIYPTZzqWyt0/aHrFw3xW6uU4d44/Hp@vNnXxDqFanFap@D14/3QMsPvmvflWma5ODpLEh@/fN0JGQ9EifZ61WHClwCyWU7ponLCjzA04MXSvuFOLk/ufd8Cn0K0TK9oJkpM62otd1/rQbx0oqeqDo9pscMD@xe0UKHXtPrFT1TawwPQQH@6BkEJVpc0SNaoRWGOcDz/v@splZqKqBSIZu5ok2ElRbhPqrVKoBMhIIn8CfRNKJvRS/gn5ZxyzM/PdEk6aUfHoh70vWzAF0pyLiDtDsYc7ulx2hMe/7yEoo93@OBNpp8vBdWkvnoIv3up4f7ZDLpfrw4oYyHB8rSLq5QxHWBQF5enp6yqXbq6YlC6w6ry1PfZ1/gM3yurn2X9u3TCX@NGBq8/PhAuD3LXq@Hvr3lYmmFcMCK620T9x9wAD6Ld/IeBt4RAY/nPvr45cXr9X54cF@4rZp4PAJYjx4X87AKiWTIhY2yJKhkJowG/ljUe30di8JzLOENeGiUamV4cGma9uAK4klqEO/PXl2ldJ1dI8PUE/HCqPDgYvWnB9d96PHqKhlFecOBZIRU9UAy7HV5vT8xl5d2ESEvRLvcK5equ8kvL/t/ni8vlx788aI/rxdF2tdrrweSvVF4Wn3xrC49lx4UB1Eo15eXaxTEcF8gdO/xPnpfXqw4uHq8lxbOay8wDs3E/3/6Vw3S0Ej3ycsJGtgVMhL1wjxf8EZinoQvaf9dfYTKeFxhdxjq6HKz7vv7z2fhs3jk/tPj2eOZ5/IsePZw/XigKr3uExKE2hHCK@YE8ZA4CV40XUzI5UZCeYFWt1VZCMow6w4nLw6lwv3kOXv9STBJ35nv8/1ZMmmVfXb2y0foP4AOCnPB5wQEmfSQl9eXW@naofRew/cLaTMcwi9fQOCsNLATPPYy9sPDiqYx/MXw6vTLCftygdGTLy73xYHcYvQe9wXe33B9cZ2y@j3z6HpxnX4ZviB76ozx4mE7Grm4OItY4XjiAoZP5sxOoSHFDkKCYLAc7sAwYCLJcgPLvVCpq6EwkmDo0Q545ItGo1QIrqsfYrnQirhA@wDWpoMr4LI6EplIYoQnpGEkCTDZh9DwSzJOw5RMllmdVEXxoxUPcw9yKAhg/gmyjFbQkGkOFqrML2E6@JE4AYUDhikkw2dWZ4W5ICzn86Ww/WQk45ydTGBmiT9/@N1f/xP4/j18/8K6/8X/kYyi6x9@9z//b7//m7@FyP8I3/8bvv/hD7/7V39qffHzP8D3/9mL@wf7uwdnfQnA9T/84Xd/@Xd/@N0//y18/1f7@9vX39//1b@3/v@T/YeCf/v7v/oHdLEeANdf//nv/9U/AxL/CoX/KYTh347@Mzu4F2sF/8wJQr5/8wr4z//wu3/5d3b4n@2D7MVD1j@D@L/Zi/8zgkCN@ZGMxv3@YDAIF3T34w@@B09/ckCY90fZE5KooFW8JGPtaUooC4R0IUkUQA5m6I0b9GqmiSw6mOnRRBBJTSiUTEQTyXAo4U8kE5EoE4tG/UzIz8QT8STtB1suwcQS0STjT0SS4UgkkvSTTCiajIPlr/CSSFFgiDAuF4kDksIh//dL9CKBGhxfEye8IMJ06gO58vDeDye8E0HOE6QrnHigSZc14/OQXvILGv08pAETf6DcQ/vnoPOjn@YJVyzuOj@Du@uTKwzBlYek3dB1Xe4Hl8t7n3z85IpHXedgOQbcPzKfwD5LwiwwHndB13ZBFaIuV4wMxV2uAUi7MAq4ydUn18ULkOzwYlsZEobJYJCEL9hwKF27sujxuJIeEveL5IPL0hpWF3R73O54yO32ui8AyUfStdcq3gtUOaibVTWHQEQTEJiE4e5CF8y5rniSAVDBZCDpvXixSPrv9mjSpzDvZHU098NFnpOuWNKFogHk0pPEZV1Hh2fnfibg/0xYCiHGECcvBI@8fCNJ8iJ5gSxIGLQur23qbsl1fOQr7NF7QZy6EcXu8CvhwjuMJAl2WCCsRtST09NTMF/b166wqxZ8uqRs8/Oawnbnw/WF7yqS8WErLujYudfIdH7ziUQIXUBbfTx61d6yCRJRxJcRaZwAugvfP@YThHKvAClxgUYL14lmjVdrZLqTDxatl785wXYDWf/ibOXMFbwudV5Bzcaet/C7FPePpPc3VUn@kggHrvEszgPNREJDvbSSP8V/SvxU6dQ6tfxn@jxxnnh4eGv8EifGL141yvxGKV2cnGvucARx@OHqxKovE/eeXIfiQYNdnzzaPgqeSBzkh4RnPGiEmBMRWWA7Q@2NgbYXOvK8XMzwJAFISfwJPxpJoT@p/PzLKUW53STJnMZ@E7i0/i/hkqlZNLhiUZcXOXcYPz399HQCIwPpCkWRhPso0lb@@yPl6kzBf8KZgf8EYRdhwKPzhNIF7xlM9u9CoIGSyVgidkL8kaK@tioLqdtlClGA6ft8dmydIqVLFRat4SjbtQoIVOYbQYc79CNDlfitqiKRrkILcUhZ7cfZ@msvCp8jcRi3NijkeYFiQY@jEwfwWSKkiHSGB9k9Jt7TI8/QKR7I48RLfCE@AK45Z2KnDbhcEMQHtEeJHj0OnJ/80TC9aK@H9hIfPlhaAoCDhvmEkKNMdmSAuSBeCMQelucNEi0h4a0by02FRbuDqmY5mclr0spkYC1LINrOsIcJKneP4DNStKiA2pyRuERMOaqcVfwHC2w4FxEp@WI5B3nIK1LES5F2bpc@RC/c4up9FL124SQNUQgLAsecwuAIENBBpAfj9s6QLwznwZA@kkHpIl7SBCgYhfyYEj8p2hnv0eMjZEfoRU5WDUBsle6xakCePdnF2nWw6cGVABai2mGFjQKsPuL8duuh167uH2GEcnbzPSiVvCRD3u3@s40LGsM6agVn5Ga8JTj4TWabzRgb8@iHpr2wto49Wzg7ZseoF@LM9M8urKbSLohbD@f9gpa8Ln4z@/FH7iftfvZ44Z1dmeju881g/Jh6JAvkzLyaXYF4aPfS44V57/NJj1cz760HPcPQdEUDsGgx2/DadYOaK1dAC1oWN7z@zb0S@I3y6M/fKz4gee4/G1xt/OwV7V/BV7pi/LL/@Yqx6wFlmlcbn3LBXsIXrb4dbM/DWOpjLw537CHL1CNfbe7ZxyvghwwZfb48VAboNO5ln@/RC4XLkPg244X844@sT75eXciBgBdB/RT@lL83IfDou0LP5x72cvVpcz@H/OceuF9BMbIXiId8Nq9ftrQDfRfAY6tNd6RbNK4QeSsgb3Z1dTb4dDY4u/r4cXO/Cswe/Rb7z@mdNCDiV4j4HdUghmcDL/mKJXgu4nH9IJ3/EDwzSJdf8vmAyX5tL6dF4dkAUjQYEG2qX5C@xOdtOCu7SMLsrXrrDWn8QifeqEHn5yAHJBXFIZ8hyJsyOEmywS1nL00SePQijWT4YfagBFgMgdLsE2lQ4sPq0yfCKdreR4aSkXIZCiSLXLXw8Q86mhnh040MTpfQSTtf16/H1LCjc7d2Y6s4yJFgo4Zje90Vqybc4Qydu0cgSA18oV8uLI1leQ@AssHaA2Cw9kBwAaRFEJNsPWFDXtmJyCa1GwhyIT0hWq7J6H1gA@knUG@7ng8qxCIDOvMRMiT/5ArrJpAnCUKkdInLgwB0FeIDVALRgOogPZLXoMjIH38k7cfLK7C742gsQGAIbuJjENAbSqHw76AUcCAqJyCjSB/iQoC2DygFOb0cFBT5ryvIdhzzQAbfxG/5jwVDdy4/2kExLH9JxDevRQZqiw8fJmBC2gTBP7afIT@kvfzxxB7uz8lMrVLvtHPNSqoFVyYUSRAnpD3Gn28Po3lzqoWGTqsYSgr28ODYJiP0SxzYL2ANgkipPDr8iCdLnTLMj6pZP3rLAliP/O8EPKCebzEJBn533Qiq@ohaSlOJOjzeDDJZziT4JLUAXvYHowaRgwdneefFuXPiNNDMDQZz2zX84NysmWAY9mEdAef4LHxEGPZnnSG3TOiF9uEeeJ/O2WrAG1toUcCPt0t1aSThM5HGFoKD/PgcBtPKjvsHgQ7l4FmTRRJNJBM0fU7SfhRgnEDICYSdQMQJRJ1AzAnEnUDCCSTtAONgZizMTCgRDsd2wfgumNgFk9tghN4FdxgioV0wvAtGdsHoLrgrLbItLZbAeMkTh5u46wo6SmMiCScN@ZArJo6MAhrmdWQECA29gYTskTeRUF7iMBJm5HZBRaqGgEKh2O4ZtI8De@WxqPJbdPitkq0nOxLGKsKa/WCBzek6aKXcCh0ZBELnPSeRlx1BgNolOVlgwRgQTLBSrvIg/4L33PLW1tfn20FKQBiumO0zZBdgygp50PmBpC0@R5JDx5ItbKGj2CxnfXLLmD03Q5tIi8rzQwdCjDFyELeP9SNSsIij70CELAjUBjsq5b0y2/r8aJHhrxd5gPBokW@IsvBGj@VCvPFg5FdOVjz@Y2xXTnmWnSLg1gYzwD58D8vAqwZFbvtXX5hz1x9@99v/nfzD7/7yb8nf/83f/r//4X9C4X@PLv8n2CxkaAvwF3@JLv8GXf4XdPkbdPmrvUwYPnzu@v1v/y08/o//jvz9P/lLK@lf/p3LH9kighQUtcv51/8UXf4ZuvxfLn90C/jXf24Boiwu/wtxYFp5AOov/iNJQmkIyxbZb/@eJF0@MDA8tuTdW3380et9hWDLhnscenydbl25sY7YTnt9LsBrPzG7Jx9qAO8ecp1Fp8nt@h6YM5Z3C9LSHMuNkSepHaUayP7hkAmjGsERyNuSB6PHXj1wQ@3/e/KcdPsQDETjtxWuLB1u19@ut2uXimB9LgqoQyfs2KhQ2LulBKa3BMg3ngmsjSCatuAZKWPJiM3fKjqt0hlAXI5kSaaH8RJ2WU5umPSQ9hFr8L@b6iKhRcOQ5e2PD98jbKdIZq/AA3XzqtmglNcxMGXc@STvZ8URwkyDJoFsW34jxqIHzAX/a3S7lrO7Ta6Wf9Vh0GcIJuZ0XyNtC7oiXa5vwCJO2/BeZHGFD@Etem2Ae/o8/Ejse0cfA3bd3d25iL04GsmQznswhr1KWSpjm8QcJoX2kkJ7SUCzhRPrmmgo9IoGPHAgveh97Q9@qKIOs@2EC/Ucpx0QGTAXtBYK/aI8N8ZXb1FjjXyo7N4i30PJPF7Z/eRBwTrnmnR532QAnId5rl635XHU9BuYtw11PCfi9kHMQWu9j@kgz16nwNwjXnNp23JM8ljLHRb4FdTMo@87CwrR/5UFBb6zoFj02wW9blaU9wD9@/z9ttpx1MRWw@@QWR3/5GCAQkPjb0H0duoIUazjoMcLU56UPeUZLlXSc@R4PoinnNcsD87k0/devkSTmKpqCtbywGdNhSmHiqzgvSNhjx3AbJ/AOlJUXTD2X1OQLJdPxY1egeHUkQKjmh@97inZp0OiF7es9ykPx5XtyGZboRnrlFmE2mIUsjyfniRFMp@ewPiURe@OgegxyCE/PDeBjqeF0F5@z9a0rWkeFb2mbnq/jRPbu1a2tsRNPTXNTnRDISkSJnScIMPkixyz3BQdtIxZgqqIXxpAFunQ9HgRE8fqTB0Jiope/0G5X6Ev7nAjglhNw7T4SdZPcnsU2ZNoD@dnvXbW21@dlbwNeVjvNn/oEMEBM/yk/prHiLP6keKe3i3OyuaU1/r19Lb26W19nV5R0g3zNc04Eq32oPuvKzrs2WEAwB0Z4W@T4bffyntDzgEp22h07KWV4btJ5AWDg@EPUZoC0JQNHhRBPvzbJwOetoR33@P/1xvQyZ773ubDxmxrDfpmlkO2H56iGfiNaoUTPABe9CLd87a4rWhnv7Mse6KDZ3h@0oUVl4LcOaFjapqgGNsNWAfxN2ReGo3fyBCORLKP7kdo0hd@chp6v4myT7wgs2uB99iQ/j28To2bAstjffV9FUeKDis91Trr1EP7mQNTDLvdY6Dzd0SG9S@83vfFygKRttKDN@MwhcX3@YcX7l6rZrQIemXtgag6aNAT/LorfslYW2tr61Ud2Tqh29aj1vhjtWQVvcH0TYYAH/Cytofx74r1fk19Nj3bKn3HiLCFDR5WGXnjOxiRP/zbNvx1LPp2TfEqwzbTldPKB9bJey0ufa3F96TCkUnLKvk@kfyW0H23zO2JmoVsp8Iyv24IeYM5w8oyx3n2MVoxX20xVXmjE1AcajFVeWdUeTqiULc5saYz0TF7V5Z94SUkCBbhvoB7F@4IIcxBnyyBcuqG7FpnyQunzFhtz2qxY@45ZIvucdG7v4@4B0U4YbSQ@7Itk3u3TO5NmdxBmdsecFjkHhDBHRRptwJqnq81gSyI5jvaGSWhmTvcvqa24aOorI72Xr@4Jfe55CfdC/c5KGS34D7PeUApu3n3eRYHDPd5Cwem7vNbCOz6lvsX97nTLRCADo848BnF2yocPXPu84zH@0Lg32Vwyg26z7dtCjCfrEfMkRdreXVo7/qr21VVQfBbRqWfRBJjwE1F1bp/9OMvDf8Y1D5DAhI/XpGhMwyMJiAHg8beiGGVA8NGEB@z7zk2fJw7S1P2@sZuDQXSfVd7iypISuZYH7lP3IfKyCIMpeLFR7gDgUhvnh@niGTezMy@RY5dOkgobuTD8jH3gtge4D04/R6A9xdx5F1@p70OUVgN@H10oszv0fmGHKc4TBFyBvAeIQsx9Wf3VyqF2vqQFrv191vo7RoBasSAA2K1Eka7p9PBhkO2KS5MU7VDIcGpaLdP2s@DPnanRNL7KhvWCnbPfCcZR9s1Q4phv/N7v1advXyItAMVhBLv6Uerl23HBayLUdJO1@1ZqlbnAxL2dA6P32UUkNhm7SCGs9SNH48V7w1DTl6rSKy5DtUkZA4ij/Y5a1ql7/ZlkJ/7r5u@OjnBBAcaEYK9nNtSLP2q/gr7XbXsd8egdpjwqoBjhvXxofStef3VUfYV5fKu2LcNiBL9ZNZ71DjalrBjOcwO9izzr8naGxMfnbtsGflWoVvsr6x9h23bOcE3@PZ6bmHhQlaCvjiMnKKF2WnofUa9tUjkRdAxWoKoJBuPVfEtpbuqfZ1Wq@LHmhiloDEabr@6gfXDBt5vPIQPV0B/xXKrl6OfgsD7FNu@jdbU93YurF0HFXmJbU8K2YsEdY/917YuWhBRe2pma9VyHwbdeDzufbsVgXot5N2N48RXtwm205aQH73LjX/fCPlOjFXd/PiguN66lOEIMAZYvG9jiZ/dx722LtvT56/6LuSzYPc4auOa7roBe6CVkKnDoiFbsvlqAkME03PG2kgc8xb47cezNbRrhKQDbeg8PeHh6@kJOec8PdmjGGqa7TbSH0/ss@VDO38N59eDHG@md37iDS0AzGfWDxLZC3D2q5CWH8oJ@jmq7Q/EbXPNFVNynB3Q@hDaotp6RnjCjNf6FSsnxvqxKZBUTwi9MESGougFISsXgkYLn9i10i7no2XooGO2DE1V7F@jmlq/WIYP/TKcpVdM9lxZstgNxCoFv9e0R5HlkOXsi@Gf81EVfIAU@u0kVrGWkB3e@ElhFMQ7PqEkTDmmkmYd9bF1/TC8OBMmGPtoAY@HsjBDP6kDsntkNbkiQauM89JoBIJE2efdWQ4ubfQrOwFVDGR2P7rXxT@MZB9@ZPuE4dPB7HVgYKfn4B1kgwzFwJpK@oGzuy8wFrnJkOg9Yxo7aWEo@MbhFreCCf9e3o@etffwzjgfL8L30fOEWvYXa6SA1pFB5JU9PuPPL/tL0/amJdYDezuXzuv0hH38wRXepwwiHzXN4zpxOYcMoKDlNsHKnPN2rge9F35OfFCw4kEeYCRn@daAgasgow1vr3m3LqkK@QMZDuGf4oDysJWKiwUc1s7eAXZIg6yIWMu7z1Ywrh941w9oM5H4cIJ0oSVrKL8jyiiMj0HayTL50UZnbaigrmx1AechuvcQhqnGhyMFf/S4fIDF5/K6DjABvL378cHSvG@zglL0/pFq87FeXk2lUu0ZozdvUqPUONXsw3OaLvt6k0iOonIFmU9li8P1jRpvL8QQ3e430sOwrx7nV5pUmGUKWo6QIv2ZbxBeJQuRTTQTzqQ4@k68KYuReOZOvDOElCwkqcVk2uCFpjZkdEO6rVaqzQ2V7zS6o8ZEHPR6k7jSIrTmID1qrIRGoqcsup1k0WgI3UzVnFYn5pxZ1@K9WGepGOluOz0urYvL6aoYU/tSNNMQ4l1RKyy5dVTjCh1isGiPY63CeppkZvw6lTH4ftzno/qZ9ChR4PiBWGplbvmRHh1Gp60kG17MSqK2Ht8WlOfyJNNacD5tki/GFoRSLy6WQqQ3HcoFZdDsdofZdH05ZYyBxk8ivcrcHCb0WDg8TwnjSSRanJt6opxO3cbNbKrYzct3XXOw7ibqhFkw2/FOiUvKvkXN5MLzbIcy6O6qJN22lrFCqK0WlJJcnNSnN/ObuqzNp9mIVGvPIvroLj9UQ6FCo7Uo9MuEHin1@onmJJTIciuOuo2q6izcTlbLemU1Tz/XhF6Ga6WFYYxOR@9yzKRSW3O1RbnZ7NW1XmcWN24ZeZCnJ0Ttjmul0tN8eZZg2tV1MXFTbM0zmeJqMQyJIzU153vhyl1sWa4KxV6DChfYuVnxSZmaTE1KJWPd7dwW76rGALp1pSRFxPUq3U3r4nM2Y1SaZaqqT8etyEThtW5cyqhcqV6MmMVpqrDsDZLF9FQQ68OpOm335N7clLITKk@sM9NGZygs89JmyeYi5W6DmuSanBlPjcItaiKKw6lcMzajm/Jm1JoPR3yydkNnhedbPt2NNnMaU8kbkaqyJvrttChtmg2RmdaTheJgmEtJFSWaqQta/aawWIVCfUmsL6MbZnU3yUekFRehy7X0XcXXKIWavrIvna6r4dqICGXzN71R9Nan5oUNVRbZ53jGp8/nkVV2jn6XqdxRZH0WlelEvu0bxw29l6xUlkOjeNfM9Dh5kxhUptPYoEncLYqGqocSpXwqSdWntH7DTqrFQVxS8pFl@kbOJYu9TSdh5spzOVEoj7Klpp5tz7i7ZG7UWq@no0RJqJenKUJIZJvNyXDUHa76LaO@pisRbjL05W5y1ecR9ONuKx8qddKx0bwZ7t5mlUW9nfdt1LteWctUp0yunpjH2vHwjFisSolUy1QkLXtTScYac6mcS2VHnQyjCsLdM3fLTNlWe00njLjeyN81NMNntodqZDhOh9eNSp/qDgwjWpCIwaoXK6amOnfLr8ySEW8rIbXWoJmGWO3I0UVPeu7X1UlqRt127jbUcLnJr@omZ7amapSPR6c3K@NZ39zqt0SiP2HlTjWjlidc7LYvbeJUlFHa/YxY4fqlEJ3qjAoVIV9YjDYdYRaaFJ7nBY7ljHqqP7yRY4uV5hPDiUWZaFd7d6P48zM9FKr9pJSadpr1ohlqs9S83ypHn8t9w8hznaKUjkjKPJvu30xnmcGabRurzbwdG8riuq6H6ByxqvYrXW6ijoy8MeAmm7v8QKnMQ7G72kSMm/yUmUlMuSvS8arW9GV9dflmOFrHunNhwYFlqDWKGpNOTSY1osbM4ov0OmmYyo1xWx1mSikplSonQg0tFC9MMzeFFS91O91qgWfVyGCYCcdqwxEd4tPV3KgemY3i9Wo8Us4Q7eG60WT4bEJixqycmZTWES1ZDqVjVHfZLDQm7bFSlTOp3kpMh7m2uoz3WFHpCJtYnKrQvsk4WVJSdKQeIzpm1uyU88uwT7ktVkL19Zq7G7LzMCs@9w0f19@MN7WuwKryuPzcZNrdeTkjTSbdWJpr07V0i55vjCWrletEMltXmGx5tcgvx60ebWjZgpYYrqp8pl4Xhhof1sRhLbUS6UWvN2g0OjVldteYFZrxYW3Ds5No1xSbsdrKJJ7B5Okuyp38cJUVDXHSXDwrN6v5XZeKdG5m5Q6/8E2Sg/4iLN3V6HI13RXZebExipud6kqrlGRRpmah2ogilp36ZmMKKTVXXVb6K7G72aSktPHMrG4ptnxTzN6ZvmQun8rW2i1Wl2u1m3I2xc6WlWX5Lu4TNq0KH5WmzwOirihySB@05HiaDhuhTjS7yXCTG3p@k561S@0kozGdQrdSuWXGMjfj4v1aNtarcL1UqnS7Lolst17X6redNlHzKXeDQZuqteVyUiwXm201WlzolV4vzi7VVIOli5HZcFlepZeV@bw3S5Z8fVNgw@pGEJjmUi5TQgFkJ0EI80U9U60b69DzZvI8WmTVu24ypd3EUpm1yC@ExYZOZRc@ysivlnxM0hKhdn91I/a5ymh020yPw9pCa8cyUaKUFCtKd5gZV5Jr4bZQ7ubnptDihxHJZ9DapN1IdYwOt5ZuuNh40TH6MnQ@UYu205mkIQ@yiVtd8tEJLk1wvQpbp8rj6F21xKvLzKrSXWdhypFgxDodVddKd56YKoVbI33be75NJEadYWEKBc/HgzEndXxpfig0RLlKDO5uu9Ncfd6lJo27SrzeKfgSm7B@88yp4xs2uW5vajQtiMnRojhfhbUyl7hJ3NY4ubSqNjuiMIq1Qg35RtkQWSU@plMis1wsFcq3jqYTuZGY7lQVPdvhCnFBrbMUteoNzFrvLnEbuqEbdGu2pENGZUnRYl@R1v1qvx/iifTCuNV6LWaR8xXMVL81aXI3MlXtNYsbdV3OhYxOqpoRb@fLtVZeS3p4wJVvMnKdkxgwS6KxUVvvTDfpxZDoiatyJp2ID0IFkCDDkJPLfoQVOEMbrSZUuTIvyKvJfNrVfbMV1fQN@qtoctwdGxRXLrerxWVOj6olY6IQsRgXKvR0LW40n2frYsbMjrsdOZJJdkfDWqFPVdribbKRaQ3iQrROFZ@FZK8Vo7lytMdRTFOdLUwYkbjRlCivaV7nZEFn4/PaczQ3n/v49WJu@rRB/OY20RtNM8yCY33h1FB9ZlfdkkxL1bgwMmq95eIu3wMLUekuOgqRH3S08K1UEFuFbq0yZeqp5sak0skedxcZ9XVGVMRFM2xGS0VhFOfEbG4wnWQLxeci3Ref6SUj641GOF9giLjoS5sqL1PdhtZQNiFWSPVricqS32Rm46ooFIqhrN5vxvjWLSvnYBiVnsu01s3flAf8UB5ToqrUWk2aJgaxUK5313xmFnyjvmmrq4I@KqXqcvhOLCpq/a7LZBs6VY2n843MpDnIrBOxui4PhfYo0VZmvpuwyrEppRwj4sJCSHd7VEeQwkx8tRmyU4FiBr3pNFGgNjFjQ6UUYzlJjDbJ4c2M6Q2q6k17PaVuZqtBPX3HzAUfw9Q5jWiYm3r05qbnu13fdIojuVMUOYqdrSdGIT0XSsthI5byJTS67cvx3fGqXB9pvRwVHw4TTCsc7kXMZ76@NhpVopstF8Lx7NpcibnpvLpKFLRUrLVedRqRyHQwWdUSrVgzumIW6jSX1vKjKKXeGXFl1S6M8mkhJ1ZEo7IZcjMitplXi/lEzhcV2H69P6DFHPXc4mVzPBLbt3fhVoziooVafTkYZFPULC5OckX5BsbEJVtZrVuT/nTYqBlhiVBrfV8xtoltWoNGlVfqvVJlPFyO4vG6XuhOkvNNX2tKTZ@26RSH6k22PpOzmzsQuFgzGZ105FynJ91lm3SNMGO91BJscCZdltYjqhilb0WFLq1mN8m7WS827U@7mUWzv5pOYq14VJ0Lm7jZe47OhU68X5q1KG7YX459oRtCbW3Wd7lGRC9Xl1rZrKvCLZ0IlQfTziw37/hmmdv80Mz0aG0Y6pWXc18mClZBotJNhqrD20m6OL1pGIVGKEm089J6npjcxG58dRhM5hOjlujKIXlB9Si5u1wI0xnNVrNsV18NO/kyX@VDCUrzSfGleRt7LvXrA9bUIgpFGOsYv2R9hRxYEFmpH235uqZGz2AuQt8twrfKKBwylLtWizMzanzaCSeFSF7vKmp3pU66IalxE58uOel2QqSFDR@RO80eX11tlnxyGuHZ1qKTyt8pvXBG0cYrQ2diydtQl32uz/RwzdTq5Q6XVhozlhWXvpWczlb01oLgR9UU38s/z8VFN1JLRVLrO56OzAeLCaNs7nL90KQ@TI3FZbMX2TSX4TR/wyjNmaTN9BBFt7tKbppYdQrCLVHa5IT1ONFI17uRzu0kOQ3Lo2mrTq@nNUnkBgNjzhT7o3KD4YvRbrqRnBZEIyXEO0mxNKFW1WFtEMvwQoQmfOPijAplyly4lLvzmSVOjj5LG6ZqbpKisq52pGFrtEhpZX7SmVfTBSrNhBY3q9osXGhS4TmbniWyt3pflwkhF02tOrVKzBgPUmY3otZDi4Q2qEujuxBfH7PcjI4lQAdX@OFg3Uk108tyv1poGSlltBF8@vJWuSnm82mFKIi96rPxzKriPBXp1Mr9xnMjpY/a0aFpFJnVs0Ct10qtlOG4dT9VNKbVbqmlFOP0jE9X4o0xX1Y6al0K3xJcMj69i1NKiyvNaSFST0Xyz90b7rm4iDXVqWJy7dyAMatNUHbFaKem9ZezTWZMi6twJHdn1Ea8NoDeOtkQoXmh2eeb4kRZLZsls3sbnrWYaXcpT2MKq/kiuWStxjKjMJqERe9UZabKtyPzrlVd3OoUNd7E5oJ2I9xKRDmkjVLFZqwUYm9u@tlkh5k9l4VQohKZp5ahWrPiU6KCli2OZjKdmTYnQkOCKUMvVp@U6FZV6owG88xdct0iNv2hmFRKvaV6m5kus9PFpN1ZhWF61e6WDaPVvDP54iI0LMXlYW3Mt7P5TIPLsKwRrymZXG2qzbvD2bIQiRKTfPhuUomXpFFsGi8K6/7tXEvWS5tiZlyI@PpKKWH2WVN@rsmT5@rQNIfPcanbapSoXjrOKfTzOm7ejXuUQRQSs9xNRIhvimMm3lFmi/mcrzUVtbiuNyrA5ngo3L4ZUimt16ibXb4gcHeFDlj6JVUotu5KWuvmrsDPeYWQwyC@GUq/vSkb@bvsdMAsi831UGJ809rtshaNR8Xk0LeIzqrjeTYa7cVnpeoin9X02KoCWn9UX9fLQrNaIZhZpZ@b@koiwyT0yqa7iDRTwl1sWFmKy0g0m1op40SiQ68apRuukRhqxeWsU2JGDWo5SE6NGdthmylOFWtE@lkLr7MrM0dHc7exwl1DmMSWfG4eKqaWrV4xZiarYq8XeV42l1OhmmfE9mqxDNXztYapRKKrbmMwvYVWiBLcaNXIxYVKROBpaTPI6Hl1qHTYFE2VqNCy02341JHyXBV803ooH9ZiOXpVZ2FmPEjPS3xs2JnIvZt0ITkm@AiX87WNWHEQe757rkj63cQXn4HKSYjNRaMCJsnQ7LQjq4aY7DObbibRY4f5DZO7pVKRQmGeLIZCpXKy3CeMVnQG0vK8DN2VsnKoUe@2I3Nftppd8ePWoNPMLCuJQZ@Z1XutRQlNxsIUvRRrk2ZnXc2vOpIQy02bOTFN@IqNpVFLamIz283pVJ0X85HJtHCTvxHmt9x8lVN89KjYWS@e5zMhUarIrKAr@aY5TnHhfmIaXnFFLfV82yXWBTZXYjKJbkKfSlxpUu0YE2PR00QpFXmOrnxmc1KXbqPZZvtOmXTG1arOZSqhuCFkp61ZbNCZrIYLIceXCNFMLjh5dVONmUp6nZfuOpVGiW/Ra66eKFXz@ooeUvnnFr0wqU6iVW@PhlVdKk9g4PT1O6qakEGlmGO1QbDauEgvu6lbPjEyMjd0olxa1TpS1Uc3cs1JNmQsdB81ntVC2Y2aK4XFZXzUbNzOaD2z4Me@23qcGkzS6rJKRE0@3GONabIpMv1@l9JyzY1hVBKdoe@2IVNCMzSIpwsbpj0Ma/x83E/0ZzeL536/8jzstgrQnHc@IdaqPBOjxm3BiItJjuE76Uw5pS40uqTPmmJkVlb7nVBf9PVX2eLyOXRL5yfFIVOtjjebNFfSe0oiOxtWMux60kl0iXCuRvODsKCVOtnnfn48n3CZ8ooL36kFw3cXqa7mN3oiHmMiyQVrhLuzWdeXSMmSLx4er8ehdG4Ry1K83uwRuZov01NV6AXNQYytUkaEr8qm0Ym3W7lkM5PPFMq3uTuxnGwV2bs7X79RzORS7VjpdjyN3PYZI02lK@NJK0RMypkpT5lmYi61pLyRu9Gzq/Fg2pjNh8v4omz0N8otO5dGM0ZktWmvrMRjqUb3OVqjw7kKlRtsZCUUj66SBM@JfImSm9O7XkLKFai@PIYJdBbkf3pXmeucqBvjZA9qXtko8UynNurqBXlcBwrl4VzjxFlSmo6F8IBoUq1EPt6Tb0Wu1m/O4v2hdNcuhePifAXz1352cytmKWj1Tr81ntN3sRyYrpHIc7E3njUW1a7RjGa77XI9QnSfm1mRKebK5e7A5JlqjR7lF2YnnijkGG6WnlZz6/QwXVzmuU6v4Jv4Qm2eW@S7KTnX5VljtR7QSVpPiRMiNolV0mKWMZfRrqhHMqVxLczKRXVVKyW0WbNeCqVLuYaoTnU63Ug5n1h3nZxJ0fVITKVuusV@ZkSkGpnsJNQVDa6p@JZFDJbOy@wff/VRIYKuKxiMWKgSb/2yuH3MxcVXDp7AJ0@g19sPzp1Azj77BwmI9vvVQAuU43d10BvC5/aPmKM9ySA6jRdtLV683lsMMM5xAviGzvEgz/AJvOLBRqhLR5m3ZHyUlK8RgHc88Q4K2gfDryf/YJzDF2jwOyiBTfiNOg/mjfebtGGOoHM@GBo@jxd7W54eZp8aRCA0GauIwE@/6wd0qsKPkBFvAedqee@xbX364iA/EGdoCj5pxBUIunBW@1QMhOkQhdWaKH57NgOBD2RxNta@8vsCLMUk6FgSn@9BKn7TP7tPPvrPuCsXKZgSq8yMub7kpyN1vBBJmdQmwxW33jyTZDRColOaQj@SPlQmE7ui8Dl1cbgmyCRtH9mEP5/woZvo3Cp8ghg6xtRNkoHtsU8fSS8O@NHl3HXxRkrJs5kjhdYhH7P72OOVckVfzO6VxwvF5/OavivTx/g8KOJHxnuhzW1PxHvzEb@1T52RFefV@r2fWK@rCjdGP7uOf8Jq/50TfDqX04FmrLbfnxYCZ6r6foyI5ImdHXTEt1Fol5h9lVNSHThzrQlo6257KoGMftsPXT7MY5GLt@mohh8@oCM0Lmzfif0KfCG0@VCWuHPiA@Yn2gJHr9Ofn9uHwnDo1DO0gYbiJCvSooWUDA9KvnBSOVVb25klC@TJqcvlHsprD9pb9fq/B9KBGqJfaUe/laADmAVisfcAnATUeGvUa1GFwmVB2e6DonN8vBfolBPyo5PmnPiD4JHc4HN3nkxSwqf0wO2StEHxGRik1z5xAsfeS@ilN@xKcO22kj5M5jMN7z8HLXptjqBfV3rSWEnf5gwac/QjyB6SQcyQHKJRC6DACzojbcGawn7TOG2BHN/wy1eoPghfHZ/mDQRzrK6vkW5ELx8gfLyK83ywfr7LQ5qq5VhpkWHnxdXw2k0NjEOnSLo19zmJ/eAuIApviV7spU4gFdX1neQZJM9Yc/xO8hjhnhvvJeuQjH7U651kCZKtdyKPp6uQbu30vwNgIi9PENcnU30yWUn2WAd6oKNAXiyF7SF9PoexWxEgrYax2uMwP2kfjUJ@tFrHErYD8YL@icXKAkAi7bE7D3reSQtORYdseiy52CvT4gn5hfxmYbZzJLD4CZcEaheV7z07wE/uEQD9D1Qp@TbdKdxq7W1FD@QnCMPOCLU2MCtM/vLL1yizBfFQ/phHR/qsFkJ@uHs1tLi1w2P96tGuXa1MGzvT8Tz20TH72s3xkdjVw@mUoZ0KsfrWrl@LksJDGYD44340cnnykp92MffGI3m@1R47Plrd4tt8DL2RHuQRhXuknxzugtz3c5VFcg85WRiRhztlgc4JYy/esNPYQgcOoa8BesvNV3LGHciM3Ut/bWW/rzYnQB/u1Jg3F5ai5cA0vLYJPEIea7Xrvk6wkJ26z6149GNO0iEy6R1k1nl6T4DAvAQa0MjmqHFnTJSUoPVOKuh5OhTxYxdzC@RlxyZHWX0Pn/4bdC7EOHvInqPftzhUSeQR1rwB39Yb8ev6dZd7VT1L0x@v3L31UrP7kxvRSL6VJyx1n2CUPCdpcntw0wX58m099I/jzJdd8x3YO4bnfV3hNLojid8jgi/vMPqbQnZYhdAjecDxOf45We2bQxI@hPD4oLRzrX9yYhy3S6tvv2uBIaouDtMRzRZCJwEM5f1cftvmut6pTvv0xSfTMW78OysM/4Ixlgow2S@IfXWOpnN5PHjvx26PjsIc2U9Bb7IjC1N3KJNEx7YFM9jJF@SeUDNbTEb8hD49UlXe4xhMtsGAMTgndACQ3zrOamtWWeblrngozjZ6yZF9yocz7l5AzEc7Co8rF/jH2R37DBFxNsLd5gJ1mz37RjLwr57hdDQaQVHO2wfIWdHSPuT563gEvTWBPhzN5Gh8dCYZPrnS1vN4JD5QD64MqyDHUNQc1tT60oXitw2BYK5hor073xK3wcuRVQbrDE/7dMsv@1MX6UIKIpt42@iOF6T3YkvN5aULFbMV@Jf/Dw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

### Explanation

xEec is a pretty run of the mill language as far as esolangs go.  We need to output 115 and there are two reasonable ways to do so.

- `h#115 o#`
- `h$s o#`

`h` performs a push and `o` performs output `#` indicates that the operation is dealing with numbers and `$` indicates it is dealing with chars.  `h$s o#` is shorter making it seem like the better candidate but I ended up adding `h#115 o#` instead.  The reasoning for this is that we can insert the code into the pyramid scheme spacers at no extra cost, and `$` starts a new SNUSP program which I would *really* like to avoid. So I added `h#115 o#` to the spacers.

### Whirl

Whirl didn't like the new `1`s that were added to the code for obvious reasons so I deleted 2 from the Del|m|t code.  To retokenize Del|m|t I had to make the `B` into a `D`.  The removal of the `11` from the Del|m|t was what saves 2 bytes from the last iteration

### Cubix

Removing two bytes shifted Cubix again I moved the capsule back a few bytes.

## Driver Troubles

I noticed when I was testing xEec locally that all programs seemed to print an additional two new lines after every answer.  I tried to fix this but learned that it was impossible.  They stem from line is present in the interpreter (C++):

```
std::cout << "\n\n";
```

I don't know if this is a mistake, I can't see any reason for it being the case, but regardless when this is added to the driver the driver gives a failure regardless of the output.  I could change the driver so this type of output is considered a success, but that might cause false positives on other languages.  Instead I modified the drivers version of the interpreter to only print one newline this ensures that the driver accurately reports outputs.

Comment: The language is called ¤xEec only once on its [home page](http://paulo-jorente.de/poncho/esolang/xEec/), all other 10 times it is called xEec.
It is called only xEec on [esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/XEec). I believe the name of the language is xEec, not ¤xEec.

Comment: @stasoid Ok I changed it.  I figured the esolangs page was named xEec due to technical limitations but it seems that's just the name of the language.

Answer (score 6):

## 116. [Piet(XPM)](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html), 3925 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#z bxe xxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#xxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[        _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---4O6O@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # 
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 2 5 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","xxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","xxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __"};
//}"                      _
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002514 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4026 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tb3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB/2CRWlvkuIFBO8URa3Fq0iK96tISVsbxIUECQIQAF7X1omeF9vd45jxtHs62seePu4OT0RHzDx5YiI84Y6YCPvVX3F@YM4fnMkqALxI1Fprtz2UCBSqsrKysrKysqoSxRGjT/74xzP0IRuKtBlLikEavG6QnCYuec1PZjbkZ0bUI8EQQSCotDZezHnZ0C@JM5ImRZkVOXgkDWXGy@KW1yA6SKqaMtaYOWlMGIPkdZZReZ1UFoa6MEhFOJ0rRObnylT0oYxzUR4DlMFrqsYbODlMdmWJmY845lVC5Lg0VYNknczx0i/zXwySVeZzRuZ0AIySuXomX0m/yh8jq4qm8wgLy@u6guLi5H/6d@s8zx6BmgxoaAq3YBF9xoSHdFQlQZR4nWCh9GtStdjoRwHyjNR4hjPBCEHRSJSFnM8kUiRZVSVHEjPxs6QkAmwhECd5xAJyC@lnpK7M@UMCdFLmeY7UVZ4VBZHFpZL82uBlXVRk3U@K7IxciZJEcrwEGfaksF5ARi70gyizYD/BKQQJH1Z9Rfju6ZwHGJm3K8@rjIYrryCGASdsHqw0RlWBSOBeGwg3xDk0uWg4dZJndBGJFGTReZnDfFN3wqaQjHxYS3IpMiQD9C40jFvnNQOq58d4yQmv8YCS2bW5a6WJBrAAsTVNNnhGIzsaz7uPRe@oSChMQSUYqCJ@3GxXV858veCE5jNz@BnVIM60UKdZJhjSnyLPn5LwTTkcSSJfy5Ffzh9Q2BQ2aGJVczFuMvUbUqceHnj4rukRNdZeCMBKAFckklJUg2J8KhDoM4BAikFBFPItg35VOiiYvHrVFgdCZUJx0BpkSSZ7XlwzdqFpqDftmcrMoNKSIo@Bn1BZbSEjfshkNABNwCrQH7wkvwSuKbLZRsoKc7gzEaHRdNQkzAgYxLCI96ZGwAwFnQCyZ3HULldXpAWGg5y6gQQQuAJZEcaSQPZIgREllAXSESqTao3XF5KB8ixkDrU8dHqe85M2GazCIaC5soTiGECKI6APzQ96HiYKgKEhFFxVlPT7f/GvufEY8KRZVtE4S1x7JKewWHcxmFjQCiQSWEVmJEwWwHlR6WZ2KGDJSCLHGKh4eWMVgYnApa6UhcSRChSorUToWhNmCd1REHjW4E0hNxWel5wzM1NfiKbkQsXnzAgaFheAy8bV9pGfs9BKLE@cYZnxzReGECd9ap506tRPrk@Xrk8fH3ggzu13X5xT1DgJAue/wFHw5Pya5PTS@waFsnSD0RWRI9SNMVHkIOljSQebUlRedjmPcDi9Tm3kdPuRHnO5k2KK9QuizLmcIOMZKNfpTrIp9l68fEy@yn1YImBZISyot/Iu1u0gQOPgPrGk5owo@9UN2fNZoYM0RX9CHEfJ/oNoxJfXcUsz4gyrfCSWCpIPUEN@XeJ51RXw026kJRDcyWqjhFMVfYXDqvCl@Ohxnjk9h1XHGKCmRxVFfbUjKkhrSepkAToamCLrKmhvDYkuy4Dw6EiJGzDkeskRFmus@UGxYJW44p0aT45Aj9pihHuk2eNQfh/SkxaGfQ@y4Y47NM8d9GfQBdClDf2NUpaUFRSMaUPDFmgQGRXOjKGJILNZobRZIbNEHHNctZkMegVhG/Fk3DcSoS@gXgeq3RL9gzoCeChowgA2s68cqKA5swEsrDkk7vsNKQrQpeagJbQNyfJI9YAO4s1xBRWywN1QB3MDGR4BXzASOe5qb3qaoVFp3xB09Zb6aodClT/sU0jfkAK/IiVGHi@YMbJ4ZMjCsCyvGpa@gproBmik18MOjvRZY6hfnxDnn1@XjccSa3Q9KAPperP1rBGRQUrGMnt8EuhUkrFsNpITNdBO0uZ16QCwfFW442cEckTAz453SLANARAyfs2zCwOUGwjyaiKyE5BdRJ1sqkdzLHpdPEQdlg4K3ifsikbE0Nc/Bgk/tYtCZLyLwoda9C0eGGMRquujCNz4hxFfx8zo8xOIlR2JMB4cxPopxg@yZzENrKc2stxgsLFNJdyzdubcjp/AYOjq0E1BWCaGoeqXoNtFY7IY@aFZqY62KRl1GbUsZWgb0VDM8EhSRqBLdehMlF0CxS5G4vpVjXDcjuFTnViC0SToZApG2@cFiIjLKeig5XB8FgEfJDmwtsUozKsDADGQHzjlEnSsPwugAdobmXU5/Fju/dBDHF7SgXqZww0BlGvHl6wyRyqD7OPBHFlnGQ3UjACqxVLUWE8zJ4enncLGtpjT6Z8qouz64vz48aPz0nkN6vjjx08QukKhTyjkgdAnHPLhEILzoxDO4cUhlHqPc6C4R@fLvY157X5EzbZGQ8lWVF3M/eVl6NHL3NPWPYjubtBLoIYA2odugMfpTqVQ0O12XK@gov6RYNa@ZXKWw9LQ4uUxwa9VRTPIWj2Xf2qkO8WUg1roGiWJI0qGwfBpDt0NJhyOE/lh5mBnh2BLUYwUbjAUj6ELAGTNjQhDWUAHhcmCOBeNEp6iSDIS7X2j2alZKNdEUDqckAiaMt@pF53g2YlCOs5DDmRIH03m0JhrpYZR6sKayx3Ex1D8HE3F/CwxZlnSp5iPu0gLMI4A0ezMDzMoYuzxIEg8W9tFYkpPzPYsDFGEgVNGvLSOhn28JPiN9daPOl00TJg30se9B3EiL7HenspAGNCDfGvhVQJjzyU7oLYrYKWTFVHHE@ND5hI7MXsgHGY3CB0rZMc@Jbi3nk6bfI5DLFgkoFlmClI6@9AT2DeRIxQwU32bUxD1Cb4cgb6h6G0Kzq3PRwK@nAC4tMwIsEnQnBaxpIxmRMiSURSY/64w2FyRFZMUYJUoM1QL3/ww@pyi51jJHxEz4oUFzJKokSij8DfAfIk4hhRGI/E9UOALIt2@nwDTFqNTbAPhmryxA8gjxhsLzZB4zrr/lz/loAHeNs@E2YB1z852gSfgG2oqn/Bua1lZ0QO@nG5ZDDNdSCKD2YBD30LJMmgGxki7wGnUSLGRPt@E0aBxN3bjgnCiCwxSX5Ezk3KNlxYcb99PF4JZfGxtmLllcY5rBHdkOuHR6J3sr2wlMz@awWqSwnAYi7myIPL71jbbhV8zY6gcdaCR/NroO@i0TRpyv5QA5oCxMK9o9eBb7Sqq6Pu1/mpBBiLMiOZh3sWMxHe4iIiIvifXZndBw7dPkJiZGXxCwdNVNSujieMxmC3W/T0wMCjB5lcZlqdW@PauipEXumo2BQp9BZ8mmdf3QOyVyl3gPUCopoQvv0bssCCw0DcQqWj1znfAIvEVUyVmtEEmzuTXyw8qEI@ToF5SrMcTCKEhczfd268Tqur7@dGIjPMnEqdzm0uKGAGrCALPf6vPwrgjzhnJF@QOgu@qYNsk3IdOgE6ZJQPGosToICCGxWZ@Cc2CL18TWjSUsAuJ0fahr4jsnhx7Vv/exHCfRxVZRRItybQf3tOFr630PRq0WIwv@6zo6S1/OTCM0TDt24VOd2iFNdDk7B05@g71ZM6L0MzzQDD8ynu8Y5UV@r7beyfKkjevp4es7UmqvkP9@CQsGTDZepudY78lrmiVD19Oc3F2kiqDlU7GX5JVRdFgYqyTQX8AGTgyXpqGAVuSzLlfp1R/X6Z1UVJ0so2vX@MFGOC6bl5PS/Mh20RG9rETs4/twqeznSQKD29kGl/faVxGGitSND6mGLi8KwELTUBa3rp/r4bbaSia/qaG2pk7ikxb93dV@wz@vyUceNFRQ9P7g@BXrKhT6syaFr5fQZgRoAW205UrBOI4p58yZ03vNYDGTlbMxr7/I0aP97hrjx7qBhvLYM2hDIk4BAzNNKD/MaWFv14a93066g3a2LcqcdC4M4kHjY2vb5qUDAboX5mDDgS@X2MJ0oJf8Cc1SH005UFsvqY7vp@ogFWNc2vdgALmoX3IHdTWmgp@F9VoPEdPX1U4jCRCJ/@mNXNS1ahgYato6tyAQAMF3mYcywv1qHEPeNdayK2vc26i2j1b4Y6IRCm/ViPFv20zHZnhOo@/pxXIJdophwmvMgcbQv6O9reQ4iUZ83qEGMfsMU9FtNqjfRXvJblbBwT7FewRaFVxpvvQktH3KZ7gezN1DJxIwFxM5o0Nur7H7VOKdKQo0q9pHdCnnIjMNDA@0Yb8t1rpkmxv5iOw3Nj9IuV3tIA9TQRuoSnxuw3bAJTGd@IMvV1j@8oodbDidrLkG0W6vrr@RqO3UN@l/XF/7KuA9nIXZQfe6YIYWcIf@h7zR7VtWrweidYwzVXLvePA2Sv1om6AMSLn09kJP@fx41cMeoabLnT79i7QWkHfE8l@Cq9AnmxTkTe@VkNzFRdv0e92cXSv5VsAcaJm7STrO3eNs5LMajze07G3DcgztNO0mMO8xVA0P4nhXC7G43G7CTMTMn3HMoDZUHjDHO2imXvxOgkTEgPDigJ5f0@ef1lfBi7pFzJFOi4d5OOjiRXv5@TXKt7pbplZ78@Zx9S50@dznjsf5Esy4MSgvASWyElQ5ghOEPHNpHNfdVJm5njjDoXtmibN3UGYIKAN@AkjcxJPdqFr4WmTopl7XOZGagetlP3nv@csv4QxD5WcizqMPGMZ@dIoc36irD6Z5Vqlp1WVQX4NCMdqgpaCUOm@bJrUV6IBwoTdEWD@0i104tbupuXlAw8NpMMOqDAbFfVqtOdumI1mUsMpvCkVVsG7XHalYIa4mMvkSuSMie4Ha19mebx7ultyhxACkw1NQVLlJUskx6OVCg4RhkVZUpQZ3htAlPznvzf3dCFRRCKEwnbx2KXjoEQSdU@8kcqyygKotpFseU2xQFyIyTDPXaBBAGSaN@PdJDth8GYzSKLP3mpFxZjbrdl0m/TlSSdySUJ7QklRcJ2nWze9@8Bj6jfknOL/y59S7i8W3xw/@GK07vCSNkjyBcnVYXIAkvepTtJxvnZY1ULOL9jXYydUliOaC4Vxc9lbp3PsN4Pljl/hrVO8Py6j8QE5pMg69A94dGPUZqdJnbsWpkrytQ0ygvy2oLszEDI9bbALAtoGRFnO1@Qv5ATJio8l6UgAnkyGSGjneZ7K2OvMocOtACrHjxZ4YWwZ9AdDKVyd86cUqGsU0nhOQY4g9z89rB4p3ebKw8P6h0BwDWxTNAD/kUI9J1/LfTn3Xwd@@UUH29/heHEmzT0R6N7nXxqlRr7dSXe6bWDji1nLs4KizZm9ikBCoEowK5soEnatAX5oIq9/W218wHqD@GABulzkOUNegTVMgob6sFMsFlsdPse5GTTTsCbZpb1KtNSHIJKWqiMbuLWthnXqh2rOawsAYh70yQXoVZt4EJwvJ9QVro6DTEGFfFAhDL4jePd0qmLHqRjeZPgn9AxMt6pxCIWruoc6DYTqagJbdJswJpEnK/Hy34hyFcaRb1OOoL5FOQAT3yr9oOBCulTptvJvyz4o1oJ5A7KTkANvxvwarD/QgwKWcNMvypQbxfLBsRUD6P2JuVPPSHvVppNLURdHEo8lSUCKWYK@jToFXp7WUecmkR7xk2lJB0XKcaAZRhsDKRbQqH68IWnuSvpk0nEGDPDvxjkv6SAQrJ5664sBimMF1iv7s5n5HMNhzDpxwnfsgad@/y/@tekv9mBA@M@ssADhf26Gf6IQg976vJg07liD2NIrNUgdRiuz4nNmfVAnNGCgAUmUYdYqzoGDS8wQBG4Su6/vHo/rvgf8hEYAZiLNh5QdLo/XHl3ICeKSotD4PlYkwY83tfg1tAPoSuwT8bxA/nugn6loJBqmKSDSt7QR@kQToU81EbrdlyBCxFJUUz@PWPLq6op06DCL4VPRpMlI6pz5KeT4eUfoOcASpilwT0IeyLLPAWnXVjbXOeOh3Sgr6oVO2kk@JmGUN9sFBgoXDgCIG0XLFj8cMBIpFqug0WV@bWClurFNHLAvZLwXzptenDYiHyAycSM3s9eyu98tQXvIB9LsP2wGRx@BtRHYpeOU6Nz/RD4YD/Kj5W1IgsD82xOCJEP4z0@4IO6kJ/3W@c312nUN1Yb83JYVtH9WAGpJV5AKhig66j7oKQ4LFdCL@sUvgBJ6AvQslheniqqns/lSud5ov3HewpDO12BO0nl95Xnw@b33j7uA85XU20zNFKh2NVOwWXlI1X4iiiD2s9HXZJ4q7TWl75TeN7eq3paNE94URAe@FzGeyvoKeMHmLfZ9KnUAmDWX0t@U6nJ/ebl/vLp@kM/eFP/LKb/WM/8FEi4IPejYq9VJntA5JXsDroPeGdD9ti9H0LH32t75jZjP@@j3Xbp2byDsHbvsrT7k1hW8hhnnkpIXkkT439kEhLr7KbMo7NNkEmbTC7rGJpVGpO4LZIk3GymH1JBWXd6@LGG5wuyYVDdnh9i/lJFhYqCJrAmtYwVtziGxMyTMIkrGfuIBkxm01IDnVxs8lwBVsduY4ES8gcVoto/OLqXNz0Vfx6YHKY69mxYoMuR@NIG6SeIoyaTu1@TOleVrHlx@XZVEw4Vcp9Z@NEeD2rjcqAL0lcQjz6urxKPl5kXa3lge7NDVWAC/GopK7ufFOd4OtWBqROYWgBzEgCfLiznACfjW4tEowZM1xQeZgY9Om4h7KMVl1cE/5yJQun/CrzlxDCONy@0FlfQDTe9dwRi3B@azTtDDJqtu0I7LIWN@lfvaAceYe8Yvyhy/diG/4stHxB2Id676S6fb8UYGsA@d5VDHvXams5UFY1i9du@I9kohJBI7RXDcdxIJ/0QnkKsRWPdQYtvQKhCEMdQlzBmVdC2wN6JO@kn86HpwyV7d0Nyk7xqNZytSJj0ePC@AG07wkzingEOihJZyXMjh3kWloJ1RrC5z6LYVVfKe9vsfIYwLcZPnaEqfBXMDTYbdBBiRkOUSo4UBGP4uEUUrmAEhisz7OS6WQPNxDaBOJuOOPJ7gDgi8wLUmr38k99pg3wNNriYSl1ZrHKvDBAlicXVCYwDaE2rOtjiBv5a/CHANKTGAysJMTwSF8vmWl2Xory6QmTn0TpJZgJBpbq/9qpZ3/yIBLuHMJLFoOaAAoccvGOSdXyQF7JlzKomnlckXGPd/fkADv2AN/RvqTyg/lfziOpdSGwqMMfe163ySoj2hC4/nXL5wncvIHPnxRzQbfTkHa@fJ7/A71gDkO5fcSZBnsI5S53LynLlynXOp4AXOAY8ej/sLZPiNTvm/nDMv1PmPYE14IUYze6frXHej7hDw@@kXoA/1kHPKCzLzxeUgHWvkJ46KPxc9HkSD//wJEfAb6qHtwePKQ5vC89@kZeRS47mtRo5tlV1LvHl7zGSgFX250@gR7EhoLkU@2cCH7xecSDtlH/3xj2d0FGZ6n6Ihl/IpGPp4cUaefXZQFw7N8eUht0w67xkh6H9@bMwajTv3g8t5lq076LADavNTkrygiDPqIvBLjKJ@/vlnsD7J@2v/tf/Rfe9zPt671tex2EXSG41feD97aac3eUZKdICm3a5g0E2RD23yIcYwF55w8LOcFEVR1TkOvsoEve0CllgKSckH@LjohtMZCTnbPyEH2k@fPsIf/ofP7hFdP@IYKxqDvP18dJOu5zVxdv1h/Y/5UDQdfEAztlD04@cPUGXegz@Xl5/xPIZ0xOIORfmMYMnJGU1HSOVsS47WPImifOhDnP2GONtCGn22gT8afXJnT2dmCcTZz1c/E2dg7J9dXz@@vHh89/6fPH7/06PH57m6v7ryX1@vr32P1/f2zPaJJM6@EGfrF@Is6IDWe7ggzlLrqxYm7D53bVLoebbAKxC@8j3eq41KPt3Oe4NXvrNgIZ31BtvdzBkNT5H9I0oMocdWPp2rdzveoJnrptTLdxsQrz8@XX/@7PFDvcL1aP2z//rxHmj5wXPtSRmGQQ6fLvzk1z9PJ0LmI3GWu153Kd8VkFyxYlq4LN8DPD24obRfiLP7s3vXp@CnYEAKLAP0jJ5Vlfr@v16HeHEdmCpaYBKY0Bywex3gu4FNYLMOzJU6zUGQh7/AHIJiQFgHxgE5INP0EZ73/@d1pVpXAJUC2Yx1wEBYAwLcx/V6FZAJUPAU/sRAANG3DizhPyDhlqd/egqQpDvw8EDck46feehKftrpDzj9UadTfIxE1ecvL8Ho8z0eaCOJx3t@LRqPDtLrfHq4TyQSzsfkGaU/PFCmdnEEw44kAnl5eXrKpTvppycKrTusr849nz2@z/BJXXuurNunM@4aMdR/9fGBcLpW/X4fffur5coM4YAZ198lHj7gAHyW7@Q9DqxPi4DLdR95/PLidrs/PDiTTrMmLhcP1qPLQT@sgwIZdGCjLAEqmQ6hgT8acV9fRyPwHI27fa4ASjUzPDhUVX1w@PEk1Y@3cFOptKYxG2SYusJuGBUeHIz29OC4Dz6mUokIyhvyJcKkovkSIbfD7f6Jvrqyigi6IdrhXDsUzUl@eTn8c315uXLhjxv9ud0o0rpeu12Q7I7A0/qLa33lunKhOIhCub68XKMghvsCoXuX@9H98mLGwdXlvjJxXruBcWgm/v/Tv6KTuko6z17O0MAuk@GIG@b5vDscdcU9Cesv9REq43KEnCGoo8PJOO/vP1@ELmLh@0@PF48XrqsL/8XD9eORqnQ7z0gQalsIU/QZ4iFx5k@2HHTQ4URCmUSr24rE@yWYdYcSyWOpcD65Ll5/4nTCc@H5fH@RSJhlX1z88hH6D6CDwhzwOQNBJl3k1fXVTrr2KN3X8P1CWgyH8MsXEDgzDewEl7WM/fCwDgQwfHKUOv9yxrwkMXryxeFMHsktRu9yJvH@huOL45zR7ulHx4vj/MvoBdlTF7QbD9uRcDJ5ETbDsXgShk/6wkoJQIoVhAReZ1jcgWHARJLlBJa7oVKpET8WYehRj3jkiUQiVBCu6x@i@eCaSKJ9AHPTweFzmB2JjCcwwjNS1xMEmOwjaPgVGQvAlEySGI1UBOGjGQ9zD3LE82D@8ZKEVtCQaQ4WqsStYDr4kTgDhQOGKSTDZ95g@AXPrxaLFb/7ZEX9kplOYWaJP3/43V//E/j@PXz/wrz/xf@RiKDrH373P/9vv/@bv4XI/wjf/xu@/@EPv/tXf2p@8fM/wPf/OYj7B@t7AGd@CcD1P/zhd3/5d3/43T//LXz/V@v729ff3//Vvzf//5P1h4J/@/u/@gd0MR8A11//@e//1T8DEv8Khf8phOHfiv4zK3gQawb/zA5Cvn/zCvjP//C7f/l3VvifHYIcxEPWP4P4vzmI/zOCQI35kYzEvF6/3w8XdPfiD777z3@yQej3R9kzkqiiVbwEbe5piigLhDQ@QRRBDubofRz04qaBLDqY6QUIP5KaYDARj8QToWDcG0/EwxE6Gol46aCXjsVjiYAXbLk4HY1HErQ3Hk6EwuFwwkvSwUgiBpa/zIkCRYEhQjscJA6IMotc5K/QuwaKf3JNnHG8ANOpD@Taxbk/nHF2BLmIk45Q/CFAOigKJowTRrtY3z@mvjiCITJIRkiadHgddZIlzwr4A09P6AkG10A2AE8kPI0khp1BeI3DCx6CCgTnzBi9io0S1uunOlZU9k2pr5UnM6VuRplXeKqTT0@OlyRBUS@Od4wYc3bqIt3kFzRSu0hd3PLAZVfAu4DxKfJpEXdEY47LC7g7PjlCEFy7yIAT1IzD@eBwuO8Tj58csYjjEqxcn/NH@hPYkgmYscZiDlBDjiDwO@JwRMlgzOEYQtfkxz4n@cmRfAH22u22YzwJQ7rfT8IX7E2UrqZMelyOhIvEfTjx4DA1nKkunC6nMxZ0Ot3OJCD5SB7W051ElYO6mVWzCXQASUBgAobmpMYbC012JXwwXJC@hDv5YpL03x3QpM1gjsxoaJ6Ki7wkHdGEA0UDyJUrgcu6jowuLr20z/uZMJVXlCbOXggOOS2HE2QykUTWLgywV9cWdbfkJjb2FA/oTRLnTkSxM7Q@7gh4N5QkwWb0hZSwcnZ@fg6mdufaEXLU/U9XlGUqX1PYRn64TnpS4awHW5x@2ya/Rmb@m084TGg82pbk0BENpv0SjyC@jEn9DNAlPf@Yjx/KTQFSIolGNseZakrkBk0zyAeT1qvfnGEbh2x8sbedFjJeQ7usomZjLtv41ZD7R9L9m5oofYmHfNd4xumCZiKhoV7aiZ9iP8V/qnbr3Xrhc@Ayfhl/eDgh42f6L24lQv9GLifPLlVnKOwMgRmeOjPrS8fcZ9fBmF9nNmePlj@FKxwD@SHhGQ9wQfpMQNbi3qh8Y0wehE48r5ZzPKEBUuJ/wo3HYvBPqj//ck5RTidJ0ufR3/iuzP8ruGTrJg2OaMThRo4o@k9PPz2dwShGOoIRJOEeirQGqsNRfX0h4z/@Qsd/PL@P0OHRfkLpvPuCoqi7IGjLRCIaj54Rf6Sor60gQ@puSUXgeU1fzE@tqaQ1scqg9SZ5t64Cgepiy2twtw9SsNUqifQqWjREivUwztK1B1H4/JHjuI1OIS8RFAtjDjqpAp9BQwpIZ7iQjWbg/UfyAp3@grxj3MQX4gPgWrAGdjCBS5IgPqD9VPTosuG85I@64Ub7UgE38eGDqSUA2K8bTwg5ymRF@ugk8UIg9jAcp5NouQtvM5kuNQzayVRU02dO2pBmJh1rWXOMwN4wqNwDgi9IwaQCanNB4hIx5ahyZvEfTLDRQkCkFEqVPOQhU6SAl02t3A5thF4dxtX7KLitwskARCEsCBxzCoMjQEAHkS6M2z1HfjusC0N6SBqlC3j5FaBgxPRiSrykYGW8R4@PkB2hF1hJ0QGxWbrLrAF58WQVa9XBogdXAliIaocVNgow2pj1Wq2H3iK7f4QRyvY8cKFU8ooMund75RYuaAzziB6ckZ1zpuDgd7ItNmNs9KMXmjZpbnO7dnBWzJ5RL8SF4Z0nzaZSk8Sti3V/Qctzyd/Mf/yR/Um9nz8m3fOUge4ezxzGj5lLNEEujNQ8BeKh3ouPSePe4xEfU3P3rQs9w9CUCgCwYDJbd1t1g5rLKaAFLeHrbu/2Xvb9Rn70Fu5lD5C88F4MU1svkwp41/AVU7RX8j6naKseUKaR2nrkJHMFX7RSeORKAGOph0keexdAlplLSm3vmccU8EOCjB5PASoDdOr3ksfz6IbCJUh8mzEp/fgj45Gu10nJ53MjqJ9Cnwr3BgQePSn0fOlirtaftvcLyH/pgnsKipHcQDzks3j9sqMd6EsCj8023ZNu0rhG5K2BvHkqdTH8dDG8SH38uL1f@@aPXpP9l4G9NCDi14j4PdUghhdDN/mKJXje5HL8IF7@4L/QwUITPR5gslc9yGlSeDGEFBUGRIvqF6Qv8ckh9io0kjDLrcB81xu/n4o3lfABJzo@1MngkH8T5E3rrCha4KZjmiryHHovSNS9MNORfQyGQGnWSUYo8WH96RNhF23teUPJSLmMeJJBbmX4IAsNzeLwqVg6q4nohKav69dTatjWuTsbt10a5kmwp0PRg@6KVRPucLrG3iMQpAa@BF6SpsYyPR1A2WDtATBYeyA4H9IiiEmWnrAgU1YiskmtBoJcSE8Ipqc1er1ZR/oJ1Nu@54MKMcmAznyCDNE7TWHdBPIkQogUr3B5EICuQnyASiAaUB3ER/IaFBn544@k9XiVgjlCDI0FCAzBTT00AnpDKRT@HZQCDkTlFGQU6UNcCND2AaUgB52jgsL/dQVZTm4uyOCZek1fN3/wzuFFuz266duJ@OY2yUBt8eHDFExIiyD4x/Yz5Ie0lz@eWcP9JZmtVxvdTr5VTbfhSgfD8f1hSZe7Y3XenM@honM3RqKMvVFYpkXzgzIL9gtYgyBSCocOzeLIcrcCc7lazoteGgHWI19BHg@olztMvI5fxdf9ijamVuJMpI6PxUMHHGHHF3wCn88@7QiRgwdnae9xunc41dEsEwZzy9P96Ly1Oa/r1rEjPvvYNXy0HPa9nSMXUuiF1jEleE/R3hbBm3BoAcOLt3Y1cSzis7QmJoKj/PhECcPMjvsHgY4X4RiDQRJNJOKBwCUZ8KIAbQeCdiBkB8J2IGIHonYgZgfidiBhBWgbM21ipoPxUCi6D8b2wfg@mNgFw4F9cI8hHNwHQ/tgeB@M7IP70sK70qJxjJc8s7mJuy6voTQ6HLfTkMO4bODICKChX0eGgdDgG0jIHn4TCeXFjyNjiYBVUImqI6BgMLp/Bu1jw6ZcJlVekw6vWbL5ZEXCWEWYsx8ssHlNA62UX6PDj0Do3Jck8ggkCFC7JCvxDBgDvAFWSqoA8s@7L03Pcm1zuRukeIQhRe@eITsPU1bIQ@NzvEzxOZEcPJVsYguexGZ65pM7xhy4RFpEmlReHjs7Yozho7hDrB@RgkUcfQciaEKgNthTKR2U2dEWJ4sMfb3II4Qni3xDlIk3cioX4o0LI0/ZWfH4j7Gl7PJMO4XHrQ1mgHVoI5aBVw2KXjFIfaEvHX/43W//d/IPv/vLvyV//zd/@//@h/8Jhf89uvyfYLOQwR3AX/wluvwbdPlf0OVv0OWvDjJh@NCl4/e//bfw@D/@O/L3/@QvzaR/@XcOb3iHCFJQ1D7nX/9TdPln6PJ/ObyRHeBf/7kJiLI4vC/EkWnlAqi/@I8kCaUhLDtkv/17knR4wMBwWZJ3b/bxR7f7FYIdG@5x6PF1unllJxpie8DtcQBe64neP3lQA7gPkGsMOoVw3/fAnDE9cZCWZhl2grxerShFR/YPi0wYRfePQd5WHBg91uqBE2r/35OXpNODYCAav1mRMnW4VX@r3o59KoL1OCigDp0VZKFCYfeOEpjeEiDfeCaw0f1o2oJnpLQpIxZ/a@iUU3sAcdiSJRou2k1YZdm5YdJDWofFwf9@qouEFg1D5psJ@NBGwnLgpA8KPFI3r5oNSnkdA1PGvf/0YVYcwc9VaBLItuM3Yix6wFzwvka3bzmr2@TrhVcdBn1GYGLODjXSrqAU6XB8AxZx2oJ3I4srdAxv0msB3AcuQ4/EoSf3KWDH3d2dgziICyAZ0jgXxnBQKVNl7JLo46TgQVLwIAloNnFiXRMJBl/RgAcOpBfdr33Xj1XUcba9cKGeY7cDIgPmguZCoVeQFvok9RY11sjHyu4t8gOU9GPK6icPMtY516TD/SYD4DzOk3rdlqdRB97AvG2o0zkRt49ijlrrfUxHeQ46BeYe8ZpLu5ajE6da7rjAr6CmHz3fWVAw8F9ZkO87C4pGvl3Q62ZFeY/Qv8/fb6sdW03sNPwemdnxz44GKDQ0/hZEb6@OEMUaDrrcMOVJW1Oe0UohXScOGoR4yn5r9Oh0Qe3gXVI0iakpBm8uD3xWFZhyKMgKPjhK@NTB3dbJvWNZ0Xj98JUK0XRPlZ3odR1WGcswqnnR26uidc4lesnMfHnyeFzZjWyWFZo1TydGqE1GIcvz6UmURePpCYxPSXDvGYge/SzyGXQS6FhjCB3kd@1M27rqUtBb94b72zixvWtm64jszFVXrUQnFJImYULH8hJMvsgJw87QAd2YJaiK@AUHZJGODJcbMXGizJUxLyvoVSWU@xX60h43IohRVUyLl2S8JHtAkTWJdrFexm1lvf3VWcnboItx7/IHjxEcMcNLaq95jDirnSju6d3izGx2ee1fT2/7kN721@kVRE03XtOMI9FqD7r/uqJDrj0GANyTEfo2GV7rDcI35ByRsotGB3iaGb6bRI7XWRj@EKVpAE1b4H4B5MO7e9LhaUd47z3@f70B7ez5720@bMy2N6Bv5nlk@@Epmo5fn5ZZ3gXgJTfSPW@L24l27jvLsiY6eIbnJR1YccnI9RQ6pqrysr7bgLURf0PmxfHkjQzhSCT76H6CJm3pJWfB95so98TxErPhOZcF6T3Aa9e4xTMc1lffV3Gk6LDSU8xTW10BL31kiuFXBDDQ5Tsiw3iXbvf7YmWCiDvpwZtxmMLS@/zDC3evVTNaBE2ZeyCKBhr0DL@ai1@IVjfqxnytSDJPdrf0qDn@mC1ZQ29bfZMhwAfz3G7auy/W/TX12XLtqvQdI8IO1n9cZfTmgI0R@e6/bcNfx6Jv1xSvMuwypexWPrJO3mtx8WstfiAVtkyaVsn3ieS3hO67Ze5A1ExkexWW/XVDyBvMWUaSWNZ1iNGM@WqLKfIbnYDiUIsp8jujytMJhbrLiTWdgU4NTJn2hZsQIViC@xLuPbgjhDAHfTIFyq4bsmvtJS@cMmfUA6vFirlnkS16wEX34T7iARRhh9FC7suuTPbdMtk3ZbJHZe56wHGRB0AEe1Sk1Qqoeb7WBBIvGO9oZ5SEZu5w@5raho@sMBrae/3iFJ2Xopd0Lp2XoJCdvPMy7wKl7OSclzkc0J2XbRyYOS9vIbDvW85fnJd2t0AAGjziwGcUb6lw9Mw6L7Mu9wuBf8/DLtfvvNy1KcB8Mh8xR17M5dWRteuv7FZVed5rGpVeEkmMDjcFVev@0Yu/AfjHoNZ5F5D4MUUGLzAwmoAcDRoHI4ZZDgwbfvyDAa5Tw8elvTRlrW/s11Ag3ZM6WFRBUrLA@sh55jxWRiZhKBUvPsIdCER68/I0RST9Zmb2LXKs0kFCcSMfl4@558f2AOfC6fcAfLiII@3z2@11jMJswO@jE2V@j8435NjFYYqQM4D7BFmIqT87v1Ip1NbHtFitf9hCb9cIUCP6bBCzlTDaA50ONhyyTXFhqqIeCwlORbt94mEe9LE6JZLeV9mwVrB65jvJONqqGVIMh53f/bXqHORDpB2pIJR4H3g0e9luXMC6GCXtdd2BpWp2PiDhQOdw@L1LHoltzgpiOFPdePFY8d4wZOc1i8Sa61hNQmY/8r5fMIZZ@n5fBvnk/7rpq50TTHCgESE4yLkrxdSvyq@w3xXTfrcNapsJrwo4ZVifHkrfmtdfHWVfUS7ti33bgCjRS@bcJ42jXQl7lsPs4MAy/5qsvTHx0THSppFvFrrD/srat9m2mxN8g2@v5xYmLmQlaMvjyBlamJ0F32fUW4tEWvpto8WPSrLwmBXfUbqv2tdpNSt@qolRChqj4farG1g7buDDxkP4cAW0Vyw3ezn6UQu8T7Hr22hN/WDnwtx1UJCX2O5Uk4NIUPfYf23nogUR9adWrl6rDGDQjcVi7rdbEajXQt79OE58dZtgN20JetF75/h3sZDvxETRjI8PsuOtSxmOAGOAwfs2pvhZfdxt6bIDff6q70I@E/aAoxau2b4bMEdaCZk6DBqyRYuvBjCEN1wXjIXENm@B3148W0O7Rkg60IbO0xMevp6ekHPO05M1iqGm2W0j/fHMOio/ePDjVmfH3kzv/DQgWgBYzM2fVrIW4KzXNk0/lDP0M2a7Hxbc5VrIhmg7O6D1IbRFtfOMcIVot/nrZ3aM@SNlIKmuIHq5iQxG0MtMZi4EjRY@sWulVc5H09BBR4LpqiJbv2I2M3/pDh9QpttLr5jshbxisBuIWQp@B@uAItMhy94Xwz9MpMj4sCv0K1CMbC4h27zxkvzYj3d8ggmYcsxE1TyWZOf6obtxJkww9tECHo8kfo5@HAhk98RqclWEVpkUxPEYBImyju8zHVw66PeCfIrgy@5/rLGHf@LJOqjJ8gnDJ5lZ68DATtfR@9I6GYyCNZXwAmf3X2AscpMh0TvRAeykhaHgG4NbzAzGvQd5P7o27uM7bX/cCN9H1xNq2V/MkQJaRwKRlw/4jD@/HC5NW5uWWA8c7Fzar/4T1lENKbxP6Uc@aqrLceawD0RAQdNtgpFY@01iF3qH/ZL4IGPFgzzASNb0rQEDV0ZGG95ec@9cUmXyBzIUxD8qAuVhKxUXCzjMnb0j7JAGWRGxpnefpWAcP3COH9BmIvHhDOlCU9ZQfluUURgf2bSXZfKjhc7cUEFd2ewC9kPk4CEEU40PJwr@6HJ4AIvH4XYcYQJ4a/fjg6l532YFpej@I9Xhov2Ckk6nO3Naa92kx@lJujWA50yg4ulPw3mKyhclLp0rjTY3SqyzFIKBzqCZGYU8jRi3VsXiPFtU84QYHsw9w9A6UQxvI9lQNs0G7oSbihCOZe@EO51PS3yCWk5nTY5vqSNa08XbWrXW2lKFbrM3bk6FYb8/jcltQm0NM@Pmmm/G@/Ky102U9Cbfy9aMWW1qLOhNPdaPdleynul1MpPyprSarUtRZSBGsk0@1hPU4ordRFS22CWGy84k2i5uZgl6zm3SWZ0bxDweapDNjONFlhsK5Xb2lhtrkVFk1k4woeW8LKibyW1Rfq5Ms@0l61GnhVJ0SciN0nLFh/uzkVSUh61eb5TLNFYzWh@q3DTcry6MUVyLhkKLND@ZhiOlhaHFK5n0bczIpUu9gnTXM4abXrxBGEWjE@uW2YTkWdYNNrTIdSk90FuXxdv2KloMdpSiXJZK08bsZnHTkNTFLBcW6515WBvfFUZKMFhstpfFQYXQwuX@IN6aBuM5ds1StxFFmYc6iVpFq64Xmec638@y7Qw/igYykbs8Pa3WN2x9WWm1@g21353H9FtaGhYCU6J@x7bTmVmhMo/TndqmFL8ptRfZbGm9HAWFsZJecP1Q9S66qtT4Ur9JhYrMwqh6xGxdoqblsr7pdW9LdzV9CN26WhbDwmad6WU04TmX1autClXTZpN2eCpzai8mZhW23CiFjdIsXVz1h4lSZsYLjdFMmXX6Un9hiLkpVSA22VmzO@JXBXG7YvLhSq9JTfMt1oilx6E2NRWE0Uyq69vxTWU7bi9GYy5Rvwnk@OdbLtOLtPIqXS3o4Zq8IQadjCBuW02BnjUSxdJwlE@LVTmSbfBq46a4XAeDA1ForCJben03LYTFNRsOVOqZu6qnWQ62PBVPJtNQQvUxEcwVbvrjyK1HKfBbqiIwz7GsR1sswuvcAv3CVKUrS9o8IgXihY5nEtO1fqJaXY300l0r22elbXxYnc2iwxZxtyzpihaMlwvpBNWYBbQbZlorDWOiXAivMjdSPlHqb7txI19ZSPFiZZwrt7RcZ87eJfLj9mYzG8fLfKMySxN8PNdqTUfj3mg9aOuNTaAaZqcjT/4mX3seQz/utQvBcjcTHS9aod5tTl42OgXPVrnrV9RsbUbnG/FFtBMLzYnluhxPtw1ZVHM31US0uRAr@XRu3M3SCs/fPbO39IxpdzaBuB7TmoW7pqp7jM5ICY8mmdCmWR1QvaGuR4oiMVz3o6X0TGNvubVR1mMdOajUmwG6KdS6UmTZF58HDWWanlO33bstNVptC@uGwRrtmRLhYpHZzVp/1ra32i0RH0wZqVvLKpUpG70diNsYFaHlziArVNlBORhId8fFKl8oLsfbLj8PTovPiyLLsHojPRjdSNHlWvUIofiyQnRq/btx7Pk5MOJrg4SYnnVbjZIR7DDUYtCuRJ4rA10vsN2SmAmL8iKXGdzM5tnhhuno6@2iEx1JwqahBQN5Yl0bVHvsVBnrBX3ITrd3haFcXQSjd/WpEDO4GT0X6UpPCMRqasuT8zSkm9F4E@0t@CULlqHaLKl0Jj2d1ok6PY8tM5uEbsg3@m1tlC2nxXS6Eg821WCsOMveFNec2Ov2akWOUcLDUTYUrY/GgSCXqeXHjfB8HGvUYuFKluiMNs0WzeXiIj1hpOy0vAmriUowE6V6q1axOe1M5JqUTffXQibEdpRVrM8IcpffRmNUNeCZThJlOR0IN6JE18gZ3UphFfLIt6VqsLHZsHcjZhFihOeB7mEH28m23uMZRZpUnlt0p7eoZMXptBfNsJ1APdMOLLb6ilErDSKRa8h0rrJeFlaTdj@gq7miGh@ta1y20eBHKhdShVE9vRYCy35/2Gx26/L8rjkvtmKj@pZjppGeIbSi9bVBPIPJ01tWuoXROifowrS1fJZv1ou7HhXu3swrXW7pmSaGg2VIvKsHKrVMT2AWpeY4ZnRra7ValgSJmgfrY4pYdRvbrcGnlXxtVR2shd52mxYz@jO9vqWYyk0pd2d4EvlCOlfvtBlNqtdvKrk0M19VV5W7mIfftqtcRJw9D4mGLEtBbdiWYplASA92I7ltlp3eBBY3mXmn3EnQKt0t9qrVW3oisXM2Nqjnov0q20@ny7ebssD0Gg21cdvtEHWPfDccdqh6R6okhEqp1VEipaVW7fdjzEpJN5lAKTwfrSrrzKq6WPTnibJnYPBMSNnyPN1aSRWKL4LsxAl@sWxkaw19E3zeTp/Hy5xy10uk1ZtoOrsRuCW/3AbSuaWH0gvrFRcV1XiwM1jfCAO2Oh7ftjKTkLpUO9FshCgnhKrcG2Un1cSGvy1WeoWFwbe5UVj06AF12mmmu3qX3Yg3bHSy7OoDCTqfoEY6mWxCl4a5@K0megJxNkOw/SrToCqTyF2tzCmr7Lra2@RgyhGnhUYgomzk3iI@k4u3eua2/3wbj4@7o@IMCl5MhhNW7Hoy3IhvClKNGN7d9mb5xqJHTZt31VijW/TEtyHt5plVJjdMYtPZ1gMBXkiMl6XFOqRW2PhN/LbOSuV1rdUV@HG0HWxKN/KWyMmxSSAt0KvlSqY8m0gmnh8LmW5N1nJdthjjlQZDUev@0Kj37@K3wZtAM9CerwJBvbqiAsJAFjeD2mAQ5IjMUr9V@216mfcUjfSgPW2xNxJV67dKW2VTyQf1brqWFW4Xq41a2YhaaMhWbrJSgxVpMEsi0XFH6862meWI6AvrSjYTjw2DRZAgXZcSq0GY4VldHa@nVKW6KErr6WLW0zzzNdXyDAfrSGLSm@gUW6l0aqVVXosoZX0qE9EoGyz2NTWmt57nm1LWyE16XSmcTfTGo3pxQFU7wm2imW0PY3ykQZWe@US/HQ2wlUifpeiWMl8aMCKx4xlR2QQ4jZV4jYkt6s@R/GLh4TbLheFRh7Gb23h/PMvSS5bxhNIj5ZlZ98pSQKzF@LFe76@Wd4U@WIhyb9mVicKwq4ZuxaLQLvbq1RndSLe2BpVJ9Nm78Hig0YIsLFshI1Iu8eMYK@Tyw9k0Vyw9lwID4TmwoiWt2QwVijQREzwZQ@EkqtdUm/I2yPDpQT1eXXHb7HxSE/hiKZjTBq0o175lpDwMo@JzJaD2CjeVITeSJpSgyPV2KxAghtFgvn/XeqaXXLOx7SjrojYupxtS6E4oyUrjrkfnmhpVi2UKzey0Ncxu4tGGJo34zjjekeeem5DCMmm5EiVi/JLP9PpUlxdDdGy9HTEznqKH/dksXqS2UX1LpWV9NY2Pt4nRzZzuD2vKTWczo27m62Ejc0cveA9NN1iVaBrbRuTmpu@53dx0S2OpWxJYiplvpnoxs@DLq1EzmvbE1UDHk@d6k3WlMVb7eSo2GsXpdijUDxvPXGOjN2tEL1cphmK5jbEW8rNFbR0vquloe7PuNsPh2XC6rsfb0VZkTS@VWT6jFsYRSrnTY/K6UxwXMnxeqAp6dTti50R0u6iVCvG8J8Izg8ZgGBDy1HObk4zJWOjc3oXaUYqNFOuN1XCYS1PzmDDNl6QbGBNXTHW9aU8Hs1GzrodEQqkPPKXoNrptD5s1Tm70y9XJaDWOxRpasTdNLLYDtSW2POq2WxopN7nGXMpt70Dgoq1EZNqV8t2@eJdrBeqEEe2nV2CD05mKuBlTpUjgVpAD5fX8JnE370dng1kvu2wN1rNptB2LKAt@GzP6z5EF340NyvM2xY4Gq4kneEMo7e3mLt8Ma5XaSq0YDYW/DcSDleGsO88vup559rYwMrL9gDoK9iurhScbAasgXu0lgrXR7TRTmt009WIzmCA6BXGziE9vojeeBgwmi6lej/ekoLSk@pTUWy352TzA1HJMT1uPuoUKV@OCcUr1iLGVcRt9Lg8aQ8ZQwzJF6Jsot2I8xTxYEDlxEGl7eoYamMNcJHC3DN3K41BQl@/abdbIKrFZN5TgwwWtJyu9tTLtBcXmTWy2YsXbKZHht1xY6rb6XG29XXGJWZhj2stuunAn90NZWZ2sdY2OJm6DPea5MddCdUNtVLpsRm7OGUZYedZSJlfV2kuCG9fSXL/wvBCWvXA9HU5v7rhAeDFcTml5e5cfBKeNUXoirFr98La1CmW4G1puzUV1rgWpQKcn52fxdbfI3xLlbZ7fTOLNTKMX7t5OE7OQNJ61G4HNrC4K7HCoL@jSYFxp0lwp0ss0E7OioKf5WDchlKfUujaqD6NZjg8HCM@kNKeC2QobKufvPEaZlSLP4pauGduEIG9qXXHUHi/TaoWbdhe1TJHK0MHlzbo@DxVbVGjBZObx3K020CSCz0fS6269GtUnw7TRCyuN4DKuDhvi@C7INSYMOw9E46CDq9xouOmmW5lVZVArtvW0PN7yHm11K9@UCoWMTBSFfu1Zf2YUYZEOd@uVQfO5mdbGncjI0Ev0@pmnNhu5Xs6y7GaQLumzWq/clkuxwJzLVGPNCVeRu0pDDN0SbCI2u4tRcpstLwJ8uJEOF557N@xzaRltKTPZYDv5IW3UWqDsSpFuXR2s5tvsJCCsQ@H8nV4fc@oQeut0SwQXxdaAawlTeb1qlY3ebWjepme9lTSLyozqCecT9TpDj0NoEha5U@S5It2Ojbt2bXmrUdRkG13w6g1/KxKVoDpOl1rRcpC5uRnkEl16/lzhg/FqeJFeBeutqkeO8GquNJ5LgeysNeWbIkwZ@tHGtBxo18TueLjI3iU2bWI7GAkJudxfKbfZ2So3W0473XUIpledXkXX2607gystg6NyTBrVJ1wnV8g22SzD6LG6nM3XZ@qiN5qviuEIMS2E7qbVWFkcR2exEr8Z3C7URKO8LWUnxbBnIJfjxoAxpOe6NH2ujQxj9BwTe@1mmepnYqwceN7EjLtJn9KJYnyevwnzsW1pQse68ny5WHD1lqyUNo1mFdgcC4Y6NyMqrfabDaPHFXn2rtgFS7@s8KX2XVlt39wVuQUnE1IIxDdLabc3Fb1wl5sN6VWptRmJtGdWv13VI7GIkBh5lpF5bbLIRSL92LxcWxZyqhZdV0HrjxubRoVv1aoEPa8O8jNPWaDpuFbd9pbhVpq/i46qK2EVjuTSa3kSj3cD62b5hm3GR2ppNe@W6XGTWg0TM33OdJlWmlWEOpF5VkOb3NrIByL522jxrslPoysuvwiW0qt2vxQ1EjWh3w8/r1qrGV8r0EJnvVwFG4V605DDkXWvOZzdQitECHa8buZjfDXMcwFxO8xqBWUkd5l0gCpTwVW31/QoY/m5xntmjWAhpEbzgXWDgZnxMLMoc9FRdyr1bzLFxITgwmze09GjpWH0@e65Kmp3U09sDionLrSWzSqYJCOj2wmvm0JiQG972XifGRW2dP6WSoeLxUWiFAyWK4nKgNDbkTlIy/MqeFfOScFmo9cJLzy5Wm7NTdrDbiu7qsaHA3re6LeXZTQZC1GBlVCftrqbWmHdFfloftbKCxnCU2qu9HpCFVq5Xl6jGpxQCE9nxZvCDb@4ZRfrvOwJjEvdzfJ5Mefj5arE8JpcaBmTNBsaxGehNVtS08@3PWJTZPJlOhvvxbWZyJanta4@1Zd9VRDT4efI2mO0pg3xNpJrde7kaXdSq2lsthqM6Xxu1p5Hh93perTk81yZEIzEkpXWN7WoIWc2BfGuW22WuXZgwzbi5VpBWwdGVOG5HVgaVDfebnTGo5omVqYwcHoGXUWJS6BSjInSJBh1UgqseulbLj7WszeBeKW8rnfFmifQzLemuaC@1DzUZF4P5rZKvhwSVrFxq3k7D2jZJTfx3DZi1HCaUVY1ImJwoT6jzxItgR4MepSab211vRrvjjy3TYniW8FhLFPc0p1RSOUWk0F8ML9ZPg8G1edRr12E5rzz8NF29ZkYN2@LekxIsDTXzWQraWWpBsravCWE5xVl0A0OBM9gnSutnoO3gcK0NKJrtcl2m2HLWl@O5@ajapbZTLvxHhHK1wPcMMSr5W7ueVCYLKZstrJmQ3dKUffchWvrxY0Wj0XpcGLJ6KHefN7zxNOS6ImFJptJMJNfRnMUp7X6RL7uyfYVBXpBaxhlapQe5mqSoXdjnXY@0coWssXKbf5OqCTaJebuzjNolrL5dCdavp3MwrcDWs9Qmepk2g4S00p2xlGGEV@IbbGg52@03HoynDXni9Eqtqzog618yyzE8ZwWGHXWr8ixaLrZe47UA6F8lcoPt5IcjEXWCYJjBa5MSa3ZXT8u5ovUQJrABDoH8j@7qy40VtD0SaIPNa9u5Vi2Wx/3tKI0aQCF0mihssI8Ic4mfGhItKh2vBDrS7cCWx@05rHBSLzrlEMxYbGG@esgt70VchS0enfQniwCd9E8mK7h8HOpP5k3l7We3orkep1KI0z0nls5gS7lK5Xe0ODoWj0wLiyNbixezNPsPDOr5TeZUaa0KrDdftEz9QQ7HLss9NJSvscx@nozDCQCWlqYEtFptJoRcrSxivQELZwtT@ohRiop63o5rs5bjXIwU843BWWmBTLNtP2J9jaJuRjZjIV0@qZXGmTHRLqZzU2DPUFnW7JnVcJgmYLE/PFXHxXCa5qMwYilInLmb6Rbx1wkv3LwBD55Ar3efnTuBHL2OTxIQLDerwZaoByvo4veEL60fo4d7Un60cnBaGsx@Xpv0UfbxwngGzrHg7zApwULRxuhDg1l3pHxUZS/RgDe8cQ7KGgfDL@e/IN@CV@gwWujBDbhN@pcmDfub9KGOYLO@aDRgVWPyYMtTxd9SA0iEJqMkQXgp9fxAzpV4UfIiLeA8/WC@9S2fiB5lB@I01UZnzTi8PkdOKt1KgbCdIzCbE0UvzubgcAHstgba1/5LQSGouOBaAKf70HKXsM7v088ei/YlIPkDZGR5/pCW3GzsTJZCqREqtPRmt1sn0kyEiZDUFbwR9KDyqSjKQqfqReDa5xMBKwjm/DnEz4gFJ1bhU87Q0euOknStzv26SPpxgEvulw6km@klLyY21JoHvIxv48@puRUIDm/lx@TssfjNjwpw0N7XCjiR9qdVBeWJ@K98Yjf2qcuyKr9av3BL8Y3FJmdoF@Rx7/IdfjOCT6dy@5Ac0Y97E9LnjUU7TBGQPLEzI864tsotEvMvMopKjacsVF5tHW3O5VAQj9ViC4fFtFw8m06quGHD@gIjaTlO3FYgS@EuhhJIntJfMD8RFvg6HX6y0vrUBgWnXqGNtBQnGhGmrSQou5CyUk7lVXUjZVZNEGe7LpcHaC8dqG9Vbf3eyBtqBH60Xn0uw4agJkgJnuPwElAjbdG3SZVKFzh5d0@KDrHx51Ep5yQH@00@8QfBI/kBp@782SQIj6lB25XpAWKz8Ag3daJEzj2XkQvvWFXgmunmfRhupireP/Zb9JrcQT9EtSTyojaLqdfX6DfdHaRNGKGaBONWgAFXtAZaUvG4A@bxm4L5PiGX75C9UH4GvjkcSCYZTRtg3QjevkA4eMUnOeD@VNjLtJQTMdKkwwrL66G22pqYBw68dKpOi9J7AeXhCi8JZo8SJ1CKqrrO8lzSJ4zxuSd5AnCvdDfS9YgGf0A2TvJIiSb70SeTlcg3dzpfwfAQF6eIK5PhvJkMKLkMg/0QEeBvJgK20V6PDZjdyJAmg1jtsdxftI6GoX8aLaOKWxH4gX9E4uVCYBE2mV1HvS8lxacig4EdZlycVCmyRPyC/nNwiznSGDxEy4J1C4q331xhJ88IAD6H6hS8m26XbjZ2ruKHsmPH4adMWptYFaI/OWXr1FmCeKx/NGPtvSZLYT8cA9qaHJrj8f8haZ9u5qZtlam03mso2MOtZvtI7Gvh90pg3sVYvatfb8WRJmDMgDxx8No5PLkJj/tY@71R/Jypz32fDS7xbf5GHwjPcgjCvdILznaB9nv5yqD5B5yMjAij/bKAp0TxiTfsFPfQfuOoa8BesfNV3LGHsmM1Ut/bWW/rzZnQB/u1Jg3SVPRsmAaXlsEniCPMdv1UCeYyM6dl2Y8@uEp8RiZ@A4y8zy9J0BgXAENaGSz1bg9Joqy33wnFfR8IBj2YhdzE@RlzyZbWX0Pn/4bdC7EOGvIXqDf4jhWSeQJ1rwB39Ub8ev6dZd7VT1T05@u3L35UrPzkxPRSL6VJyx1n2CUvCQD5O7gpiT58m099I/jzJd98x3ZO7rrfV1hN7otid8jgi/vMPqbQnZcheAjecTxBf51XPWbQxI@hPD0oLR3rX@yY2y3S7Nvv2uBIaqSx@mIZhOhnQCG8mEur2VzXe9Vp3X64pNhGzfevRWGf5AZSwWY7EniUJ2j6VwBD96HsbujozBHDlPQm@zIwtRsykTBtm3BDLbz@dkn1MwmkxE/oU@PFYVz2QaTZTBgDPYJHQDkNY@z2plVpnm5Lx6Ks4xecmyd8mGPu0mI@WhF4XEliX9r3rbPEBEXY9xtkqjbHNg3oo5/oQ2no9EIirLfPkDOiqb2IS9fxyPonQn04WQmW@OjM8nwyZWWnscj8ZF6cGQZGTmGouYwp9ZXDhS/awgEcw0T7f35lrgNXk6sMphneFqnW345nLqISdGPbOJdo9tekO7kjpqrKwcqZifwL/8f)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)

### Explanation

This addition is suggested by [this polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95207) by Wheat Wizard and 1000000000.

Piet programs are images. I am using an abstract Piet interpreter that can accept [XPM3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap#XPM3) images.
In practice such an interpreter is constructed by converting XPM image to PNG or PPM with ImageMagick and then feeding the result to [npiet](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/).
I used convert.exe from ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16.

I don't understand how to terminate Piet program, so I did by analogy with the [above-mentioned polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95207).
I don't know how to terminate 1-pixel-height Piet program, so I use 2-pixel-height program.

To decrease the size of XPM code, I tried to use as less colors as possible. That's why there are noops in the program. Current solution uses 5 colors.

The program is (see [commands](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html)):

```
push 6    hue:same lightness:+1    blue -> dark blue(#0000C0)
push 10   hue:same lightness:+1    blue -> dark blue
push 11   hue:same lightness:+1    blue -> dark blue
mul       hue:+1   lightness:+2    dark blue -> magenta
add       hue:+1   lightness:same  blue -> magenta
outN      hue:+5   lightness:+1    magenta -> dark blue
```

Trace generated by `npiet -tpic polyglot.png`:

[image: trace]

Version with 8 colors, no noops (not used in the polyglot):

[image: trace]

#### Adding to polyglot

I started with this XPM converted from PNG with ImageMagick convert.exe:

```
/* XPM */
static char *polyglot[] = {
/* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
"23 2 5 1 ",
"  c black",
". c #0000C0",
"X c blue",
"o c magenta",
"O c white",
/* pixels */
"XXX.OXXXXX.OXXXXX.oOXo.",
"XXXOOXXXXXOXXXXXXOOO .."
};
```

`white` → `#FFFFFF` for grass
`.` → `_` for DOBELA, also fixed evil
`X` → `x` for trigger

Pyth also broke. Normally, Pyth sees double-quoted strings in reverse to other languages: it considers everything outside strings to be strings and Pyth code is inside strings.
But Pyth didn't like something inside XPM strings, so I temporarily switched its mode, so Pyth sees XPM code as usual (strings are the same as in C/XPM).
So the code becomes:

```
//"
char*x[]={"23 2 5 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","xxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","xxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __"};
//}"                      _
```

`#` starts line comment in the Flaks, I could not find it in the [docs](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/wiki), but it is mentioned in the [Brain-Flak answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104873).
The Flaks don't see closing `}`, so I added another one on the next line. `_` is for DOBELA, `"` is for Pyth.

To fix Incident, I added some token breakers after xEec code on line 4, `x` after Grass code on line 19, `x` after `3` on line 72.

#### Test driver

To speed up V I copy V files from /opt/v and comment out `time.sleep(0.1)` in v.py. I still use VAbstraction because it gives us a couple of [extra seconds](https://tio.run/##tRddb@PG8fmI/oO8jHed8kMSvyRKpEjRcu4uTdu4Mu7iXFBSlimJknknizqRsunodOhTm0v70rQIkqDNIQEK9KFPfWrRAAX6U@4X3D@4zpKyLV98fQjQWe5yPnZnZ2eXO8N@kBy/ejWYgRLPUuVUOQmiqTw7hw8ra4y7ksVJbxAPQyaWN9iLdGS@zjstGLPz9Die6lAZABm04lk4FXgm4kV5HgZDQbSj1kAeRdOhwKfRSSgnkzCcCaqsibxoD1oDrxl1SzzlSwMvanbtDQ1l/gy1nM2jNBQGIuEGQQouzOLJ@XgSpzJDbpz@Wg/UMu/fZIyfae8Mx@O1EVdTX47@cLefpPNgkEbxlNnSv2bM5cyXboQbR756RbU6ANmpV4V4R69uSRRomygSmZOlf@fU5r1gpMuPu/uP9vc/En2Bp7c7RKsRADi0QVI4qkjqk4aiHB0dkSMAz5VduSt6Fb7rCZnbaEh2uW5K5XZZ48s2hYmmapoo6LqogH8f/EYQSKWa3p7aURTNkuEQa3wMuM3RdNxiO3sLQdD2ed6o8vcP@R0GW1jyB@GSZO1Wzlmz8y7fhy0RhMcZR91b2Q8BRdN0f8pRqNa32rdwyWEph2azjU4BBUjDJHHcZn3hmGqaATH9GPpZCIxVYcDRpxz9GGUaPceiMbhDe7SYgaNHzhFHHcehrttdrUoVTz4syXKvW6qUHM9xZNfN3ErX9WANPeDokqPZiqM6wd3zJY62Mudebph3xy0sLD1ed38fcafS9Wb779/dvX@3rDsVqr@7e7us3z94h2pIGVckE1YZee/u7p3OwQdlvRj1k59@ePdgH/lJt@e22yUZ11Xr1Dtt2e16aMvbJbfUStMUftmTZPjf0LsBK0iO3nGzA6XioMnvrzn38rkqPlK@iLM94ahHPWFH39HViXqqao@0R3tx5@rpdJAfZerDeK4eq8faEN2dqeGBeq6eZ@pJ3NGGiIZY1BNEI3WUqWN1qk417ZqeNz8nnXivE6OqGIelmZoyreoI3@NOZw@VjXDih1giVWX2ZeopPuok33ntsKcCiKrvcx6QoxA/JVnjZZWX6zwfdY367PFypdcfe7NFmoBhdb0wi9IugTLf8z3LsviuTZXE9xV7No@mKdFrxGZdVqte787uB7u9Hn6nlGbOdqldqrQRWm7JWb926NBlDpWdLZ/jhbMHDx6w@uDs9KzAcqTgPbgUbhI5gnD6hrHXkezmIyAIntFdrkRRvOXzNl@sRBDC02AiEM3P9BHoRAymQ7DiOWhVxwGhboiuWzeQrptiRVCZtBjgk9ls5hO5f56GiTyYBEnSau3O58E5YCehJsZzwSfBvOcTT@@2WpbBxlYrVg3iecWqikQUDzXHWU@hi8gmfEbiOQ/L1WYRlitHyEFkRRQZc926ooBi0UAqWwqZIzgC4yGLjVquXIbm/ZaIeYLYFVergoetIDqFTldEx8E0/n89cQLJDHi6ogLzOtQMUeifh2KtLpgla11aW7gYgVT5Kq6R8AHveW2pKjVq3k5X6kqCI8mS73avXZUiTwEP9cUhbGmU@ZCjsn2PaDrh2aG0B/E0iSehPInHULXs66eC7wnS62BqVkkqtT3Jsoq5JenJFn4/qA4nIwgUDzII4LjO5em6Uim6WJewdjjiqyUeuEIWtLZzF6QjtDtT1by/3W9tL2mwsnP1sCK8fe3c5uoF3h4ESQhkSbaDuad1yYpsL/srQH9KmhgOjmMwarYt1Qq8YdoYPjVpLVFRskZRECbBIP@AMWCyk8Wjy0VcVKsfjiMMPbNrPioZhqHo2GZv1@/qGWcnYQr5KoBUSPEhgWnlCikkicUt0lkfN/4MGioM48kkmEM8Gm0V/OMggX4YTiEJJxMMwhAvUjiL55PhWTQMtziKF44FFooRTvaDcBGGZ4vFWXgJt6OkGTx8GMwKePn8i19j/SvWz4r3Z3@zDNa@fP77v7z4@htk/gvrP7H@4@XzL39V1Jz@Duu/N3jfretGv6JyqOu3L5//8duXz3/3FdY/r@tXr9cXn/@9eP6zLgz95sXn37GmIFDXF5@@@PITNPFzhv8GcXzW7GdrdINboM8uUBz3p9c6f/ry@R@@XeOfbHbZ4OPQZ8j/eoP/jOPYZm6B0SiXZVnGhr3LOeRvefvwoov25ihLgduL5yFYGm40pMcRG4LYPLS49/AcnCwGxxAlEKUso4tGoHIyOzW6bpmGaVV1s2xaZs3Q6oZR1vSy1jAbllrGXM7U6qZhaWWzZlVrtZpVBk03rAZHw@kwGikKJiIaIZAj0XQwWQxDJ0mHUSwfuxwdhpjthrcgE4biLTq8YMDCBFI1fRWIomBmfRzMpczrtpZEr4IOBmhAyqQDA6Dv5oBUj1EYXNXbKlKAVH8SDB4hnuX4IkQ0RvQkGIfTNGCCLOt18ovq4hV3srhXSDoFq2iR6kCvR1Y2pygr8oYkhmOpNt4FIixZpBYgiT4O0cuCWl5gfDJ2FiapN0hTwjfZIVVEMwFUHq8ZwvuEiJ7V3SENgzQxy63wP9Z2MJe0SJM0GgSvIaKjvw1C6qA3CPklfprhuMLDDrFX6N6Lfbt0PGBIl2XAivkmk89ahT0CsQTIv2HLJ8UNV1wXvMDzDZ3nRd5GJVuwuU7RZovDtRVLuzCQoElooIWh2Z6H6WI@FawKhguoWKK9Kkz60YZN80fNJA3mKTwppmwCqVuEsbGLI1j5XK7Rl5plrVJuc8XlVdc4uuKGEUapmgW2ZbNsFwOs466t@zmcN8al9zbstbltnlnMV7PrHwKDbQDMGSvVuBbT7e1tTLU/cEmVdOSeo6xTZVfJc2TftUut2u1SnnHKFzm5y9L870Gtxs3DMeBCWmR97QqmwfwyhoSiOrv0Q0DGeVuolLNZZCN0VpzIc/abAX5hq/OU5jkO7C/XxowW0/wHr7nHti1o3k/RnrHXBfHpL6LJ0qxW3P3cQtwmwI1a3bcOG4fm4d5B56Dzblttmk3T92844zR5IsaG9nT6M5s2Z3y1xlcxDW/RYr1aQ6Su3pCT4Jx2abHHQq2B5weQzgOcrtERyxavksrvJZMb2A302elJ/kODpphv4T9ypL@1d/RkW1F4HkDbrj@tOMXjYHO7U9hA6gYRKbooOewd9ihGMSC6wU54SYF1oNqM6pk0zUsoJXkJwytGguQFxeShKCmK8pGOt6Vl1c065f4L)
(polyglot.VAbstraction: 1.284 s, polyglot.poly: 3.349 s). Also, I fixed code that produced VAbstraction (previous version removed everything except line containing `␛dgg`, [link](https://tio.run/##tRddj9vG8dlE/0Fe5nYv5YckfkmUSJGidLGdpm2uOti5OAip01ESpaOtE2WRuuNFltGnNk770rQIkqCNkQAF@tCnPrVogAD9Kf4F/gfuLKmzdf7oQ4DOfnBmdnd2dvZjhoMgOXn2bBik4MI8nl5MpnEqM4Sj84v0JJ7pUBkCGbbieTgT@Ctd@DK/GPCivAiDkSDaUWsoj6PZSOD9THtnNJnwoj1sDb2o2bNfGv3h3iBJF8EwjeIZSjlnUs4XURoKQ5Fw83AxhcrpMh2bUJnfBD5RjoR2U2jv@CGKFWVR2lWUiQ2JIks5CykenKsL2F7Q9nwcW@xrW549o1odgLTrVSFu69UdiQLtEEUiC7Lyb5zZvBeMdfl@7@DewcFHoi/w9HqXaDUCAEc2SApHFUl90FCU4@NjcgzgubIr90Svwvc8IXMbDcku102p3ClrfNmmMNVUTRMFXRcV8G@D3wgCqVTTOzM7iqJ5MhphiU9gGI@i2aTF7HENQdAOeN6o8reP@DaDHUx5RnhOsnon52zYeZdXYUcE4X7GUfda9mNA0TTdn3EUqvWdzjVccljKodnsoFFAAdIwSRx3WF84oZpmQEw/gUEWAmNVGHD0IUc/wTaNXmDSGNygfVrMwNFj55ijjuNQ1@2t16WKJx@VZLnfK1VKjuc4sutmbqXnerCBPnB0xdFszVGd4O75EkdbmXMrV8y74RYalu5vur@PuFPpefOD92/u3b5Z1p0K1d/du17Wbx@@QzWkjBcka6wy8tbNvRvdww/KejHqZz//8ObhAfKTXt/tdEoyrqvWrXc7stvzUJe3S26plaYpfNyXZPjf0H8NVpAcveFmh0rFQZXf33Bu5XNVfKR8EWd7wFGPekJbb@vqVD1TtXvavf24@yJ3u8iPMvVuvFBP1BNthObO1PBQvVAvMvU07mojRENM6imikTrO1Ik6U2eadkXOm/NpN97vxigqxmFppqZMqjrG76Tb3UdhY5z4LqZIVZl@mXqGWZ3mO68d9VUAUfV9zgNyHOJVkjVeVnm5zvNRz6jP76/Wev2@N1@mCRhWzwuzKO0RKPN937Msi@/ZVEl8X7Hni2iWEr1GbNZlve73b@x9sNfv4z2lNHN2S51SpYPQckvO5tOmI5cZVHZ2fI4Xzu/cucPKnfOz8wLLkYJ353njNpEjCGdvGHsVyV5/BATBM3qrtSiK13ze5ouVCEJ4FkwFovmZPgadiMFsBFa8AK3qOCDUDdF16wbSdVOsCCprLQb4ZD6f@0QeXKRhIg@nQZK0WnuLRXAB2EmoifFC8Emw6PvE03utlmWwsdWKVYN4UbGqIhHFI81xNlPoIrIJn5F4wcNqvZ2E1doRchBZEkXG3NSuKGCzaCCVrYTMERyB8ZDFRq3WLkPzfivEPEHsiet1wcNaEJ1Cpiui4WAW/79ynEAyB56uqcCsDjVDFAYXoVirC2bJ2qTWDi5GIFW@imskfMB7XkeqSo2a1@5JPUlwJHRMbu/KUynyFPBQXx7ClkaZDTkq27eIphOeHUp7GM@SeBrK03gCVcu@eir4viC9DKZmlaRSx5Msq5hbkh7s4P1BcTgZQaB4kEEAx3Wen64XIkUXywo2Bkd8vcIDV7QFrd3cBOkY9c5UNe9vD1q7Kxqs7Vw8rAlvXzm3uXiBt4dBEgJZkd1g4Wk9sia7q8Ea0J6SJobDkxiMmm1LtQJvmDa6T03atKjYskGxIUyCYX6B0WGyk8WjyUVcVGsQTiJ0PfMrNioZhqHoWGdv12/qGWcnIXp7tgogFVJcJDCtXCCFJLG4ZTof4MafQ0OFUTydBguIx@Odgn8SJDAIwxkk4XSKThjiZQrn8WI6Oo9G4Q5H8cGxwMJmhNODIFyG4flyeR4@h@tR0gzu3g3mBTx9/OVvsPwNy@fF9/O/Wwarnz7@w1@ffPMtMv@N5V9Y/vn08Ve/LkpOf4/lhy3e95uy1a8oHMr63dPHf/ru6ePff43lL5vy9cvlyRf/KPJ/Nomh3z754ntWFQTK@vKzJ199iip@wfDfIo55w360Qbe4BfroEsVxf36p82dPH//xuw3@6XaXLT4OfYT8b7b4jziObeYOGI1yWZZlrNi3nEP@lXePLrtob/ayFLj9eBGCpeFGQ3oSsSGILUKLew/PwelyeAJRAlHKIrpoDCons1Oj65ZpmFZVN8umZdYMrW4YZU0vaw2zYalljOVMrW4allY2a1a1VqtZZdB0w2pwNJyNorGiYCCiEQI5Es2G0@UodJJ0FMXyicvRUYjRc3gNMmEkXqOjSwYsTSBV01eBKArhhifBQsq8XmtF9CroYIAGpEy6MAT6bg5I9RmFzlW9riIFSA2mwfAe4lmOL0NEY0RPg0k4SwPWkGX9bv5QXX7ibhb3i5ZuwSpqpLrQ75O1zSnKmrwhiOFOA7ztAoiwYp5agCT6JEQrC2p5if7JaC9NUm@QpoRf0iZVRDMBVB6fGcL7hIie1WuThkGaGOVW@J9qbYwlLdIkjQbBZ4joaG@DkDroDUI@xqsZTio8tIm9RvNe7ttzwwO6dFkGLBhvsvZ5q9BHIJYA@R22fFK8cMVzwQs839B5XuRtFLID2@sUbbY4XFuxtEsFCaqEClromu1FmC4XM8GqoLuAiiXa60Kln2zptLjXTNJgkcKDYsomkLpFGBu7OIKVz@UaA6lZ1irlDlc8XnWNo2tuFKGXqllgWzaLdtHBOu5Gu1/CRWNSem9LX5vb5ZnGfDW7ehEY7AJgzFipxrWY7u7uYqj9gUuqpCv3HWUTKrtKHiP7rl1q1a6X8ohTvozJXRbmvwK1GrcIJ4ALaZHNsyuYBrPLBBKK4uzSjwEZ522hUM5mno3QeXEiL9hvBviFrs5Dmsc4cLDaKDNezvIfvOY@27ageTtFfSZeD8SHv4qmK7NacQ9yDXGbADdqfds6ahyZR/uH3cPuux21aTZN33/NGafJAzE2tIezX9i0OeerNb6KYXiLFuvVGiJ19YacBBe0R4s9FmoNPD@AdO7gdI2OWbT4Iqh8JZjcwl5Dn5@d5j80qIr5Fv4JR/pb@8cP8PeY5wG03frDilNkB6vr3UIHUjeISNFEyVH/qE/RiwHRDXbCSwpsHNW2V8@kWZ5CKclTGL5gJEheUqw9FCVFUT7S8bW0rLpZp9x/AQ)).

Answer (score 6):

## 117. [Stones](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Stones), <s>4001</s> 3994 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#z bxe xxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#xxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[        _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \)4O6O@.>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # 
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 2 5 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","xxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","xxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __"};
//}"                      _
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002493 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4096 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB/2CRWlvkuIFBO8URa3Nq0iK96tISVsbxIUECQIQAF7X1o6eF7u7xzHjafd0tI89fdwddkRHzDx5YiI84Y6YCPvVX3F@YM4fnMkqALxI1FprHzclEoWqrKysrKysrKpEYcTokz/84Qx9yIYibcaSYpAGrxskp4lLXvOTmQ35AyPqkWCIIBBUWhsv5rxs6JfEGUmTosyKHNyShjLjZXHLaxAdJFVNGWvMnDQmjEHyOsuovE4qC0NdGKQinM4VIvNzZSr6UMa5KI8ByuA1VeMNnBwmu7LEzEcc8yohclyaqkGyTuZ46ef5zwbJKvM5I3M6AEbJXD2Tr6Rf5Y@RVUXTeYSF5XVdQXFx8r/8@3WeZ49ATQY0NIVbsIg@Y8JDOqqSIEq8TrBQ@jWpWmz0owB5Rmo8w5lghKBoJMpCzmcSKZKsqpIjiZn4WVISAbYQiJM8YgG5hfQzUlfm/CEBOinzPEfqKs@KgsjiUkl@bfCyLiqy7idFdkauREkiOV6CDHtSWC8gIxf6QZRZsJ/gFIKED6u@Inx3d84DjMzbledVRsOVVxDDgBM2D1Yao6pAJHCvDYQb4hyaXDScOskzuohECrLovMxhvqk7YVNIRj6sJbkUGZIBehcaxq3zmgHV82O85ITXeEDJ7NrctdJEA1iA2JomGzyjkR2N593HondUJBSmoBIMVBE/brarK2e@XnBC85k5/IxqEGdaqNMsEwzpT5HnT0n4phyOJJGv5cjP5w8obAobNLGquRg3mfqF1KmHBx6@a3pEjbUXArASwBWJpBTVoBifCgT6DCCQYlAQhXzLoF@VDgomr161xYFQmVActAZZksmeF9eMXWga6k17pjIzqLSkyGPgJ1RWW8iIHzIZDUATsAr0By/JL4Frimy2kbLCHO5MRGg0HTUJMwIGMSzivakRMENBJ4DsWRy1y9UVaYHhIKduIAEErkBWhLEkkD1SYEQJZYF0hMqkWuP1hWSgPAuZQy0PnZ7n/KRNBqtwCGiuLKE4BpDiCOhD84Oeh4kCYGgIBVcVJf3uX/4bbjwGPGmWVTTOEtceySks1l0MJha0AokEVpEZCZMFcF5UupkdClgyksgxBipe3lhFYCJwqStlIXGkAgVqKxG61oRZQncUBJ41eFPITYXnJefMzNQXoim5UPE5M4KGxQXgsnG1feQPWWgllifOsMz45gtDiJM@NU86depH16dL16ePDzwQ5/a7L84papwEgfNf4Ci4c35JcnrpfYNCWbrB6IrIEerGmChykPSxpINNKSovu5xHOJxepzZyuv1Ij7ncSTHF@gVR5lxOkPEMlOt0J9kUey9ePiZf5T4sEbCsEBbUW3kX63YQoHFwn1hSc0aU/eqG7Pms0EGaoj8hjqNk/0E04svruKUZcYZVPhJLBckHqCG/LvG86gr4aTfSEgjuZLVRwqmKvsJhVfhSfPQ4z5yew6pjDFDTo4qivtoRFaS1JHWyAB0NTJF1FbS3hkSXZUB4dKTEDRhyveQIizXW/KBYsEpc8U6NJ0egR20xwj3S7HEovw/pSQvDvgfZcMcdmucO@jPoAujShv5GKUvKCgrGtKFhCzSIjApnxtBEkNmsUNqskFkijjmu2kwGvYKwjXgy7huJ0BdQrwPVbon@QR0BPBQ0YQCb2VcOVNCc2QAW1hwS9/2GFAXoUnPQEtqGZHmkekAH8ea4ggpZ4G6og7mBDI@ALxiJHHe1Nz3N0Ki0bwi6ekt9sUOhyh/2KaRvSIFfkRIjjxfMGFk8MmRhWJZXDUtfQU10AzTS62EHR/qsMdSvT4jzH16XjccSa3Q9KAPperP1rBGRQUrGMnt8EuhUkrFsNpITNdBO0uZ16QCwfFW44ycEckTAT453SLANARAyfs2zCwOUGwjyaiKyE5BdRJ1sqkdzLHpdPEQdlg4K3ifsikbE0NffBwk/tYtCZLyLwoda9C0eGGMRquujCNz4hxFfxszo8xOIlR2JMB4cxPopxg@yZzENrKc2stxgsLFNJdyzdubcjp/AYOjq0E1BWCaGoeqXoNtFY7IY@aFZqY62KRl1GbUsZWgb0VDM8EhSRqBLdehMlF0CxS5G4vpVjXDcjuFTnViC0SToZApG2@cFiIjLKeig5XB8FgEfJDmwtsUozF8HAGIgP3DKJehYfxZAA7Q3Muty@LHc@6GHOLykA/UyhxsCKNeOL1lljlQG2ceDObLOMhqoGQFUi6WosZ5mTg5PO4WNbTGn0z9VRNn12fnx40fnpfMa1PHHj58gdIVCn1DIA6FPOOTDIQTnRyGcw4tDKPUe50Bxj86Xexvz2v2Imm2NhpKtqLqY@8vL0KOXuaetaxBd3aCXQA0BtA9dAI/TnUqhoNvtuF5BRf0jwax9y@Qsh6Whxctjgl@rimaQtXou/9RId4opB7XQNUoSR5QMg@HTHLobTDgcJ/LDzMHODsGWohgp3GAoHkMXAMiaGxGGsoAOCpMFcS4aJTxFkWQk2vtGs1OzUK6JoHQ4IRE0Zb5TLzrBsxOFdJyHHMiQPprMoTHXSg2j1IU1lzuIj6H4OZqK@VlizLKkTzFvd5EWYBwBotmZH2ZQxNjjQZB4traLxJSemO1ZGKIIA6eMeGkdDft4SfAb660fdbpomDAvpI97D@JEXmK9PZWBMKAH@dbCqwTGnkt2QG1XwEonK6KOJ8aHzCV2YvZAOMxuEDpWyA6UcknatszOfjpt9DkO8WChgIaZKUjt7ENPYOFEjlDAXPVtTkHUJ/jnCHRHk03R2xScW5@PBPxzsjqmIQFWCZrVIqaU0ZwI2TKKAjPgFQabK7JikgLMEmWGauGLH8afU/Qcq/kjYka8sIB5EjUSZRT@CpgvEceQwmgkvgcKfEGk29cTYNpidIptIF6TN5YAecR4Y6EZEs9Z1//2pxw0wNvmmTAbsO/Z2S7wBHxDTeUT3m0tKyu6wT@nWxbDTBeSyGA24NDXULIMmoMx0i5wGjVSbaTPN2E0aNyN3bggnOgHhqkvyJlJucZLC463r6cLwSw@tjfM3LI4xzWCKzKe8Hj0TvZX1pKZH81hNUlhOIzFXFsQ@X1rm@3Cr5kxVI460El@bfQNdNpGDblfTACDwFiYv2j94GvtKqro@6X@akEGIsyI5mHmxYzEd7iIiIi@J9dmd0EDuE@QmJkZfELB01U1K6OJ4zEYLtb1PTAwKcHqVxmWp1b48q6KkRe6ajYFCn0BnyaZv@@B2GuVu8B7gFBNCf/8GrHDgsBC30CkovU73wGLxFdMlZjRBhk5k18vP6hAPFKCekmxHk8ghAbN3YRvv1Koqu/nR2Myzp9InM5tLipiBKwiCDz/tT4L4444ZyRfkDsIvquCbaNwHzoBOmWWDJiLEqODgBgWm/klNAv@@ZLQoqGEXUiMtg99QWT35Njz@vemhvs8qsgqkmhJpn3zni58bafv0aDlYvyzz4ru3vKXA9MYDdO@Xeh0h1ZYA03P3pGjb1BP5swIzT0PBMOvvMc7Vlmh77u9d6IsefP39JC1PUnVN6gfn4QlA6Zbb7Nz7NfEFa3z4Z/TXJydpMpgpZPxl2RVUTSYGutk0B9ABo6MF6dhwJYkc/bXKdXfl2ldlBSdbOPfL/ECTHBdN39PS/Mh20RG9rETs4/twqeznSQKD29kGv@@07iMNFakaHxMMfDzrgQsNAFpeev6rRpup6Fo@qsaamfuKDJtXd9V7TP4/5pw4GVHDU3wD4JfsKJOqTNrYvh@BWFOgJbYTleuEIjjnH7KnDe91wAaO1kxG/v6R4we73HXHj3UDTaWwZpDGRJxCBiaaUD/MaWFv1wa92066g3a2NcqcdC4M4kHjY1/3zQpGQzQvzIHHQh8u8YSpAW/4E9qkPpoyoPYfEl3fDtRAasa59bKAQXMQzuRO6itNRX8JqrReI7uvqhwGEmETv5Va@akqlHBwlbR5LkBgQYKvM04lhfqUeMe8K61kFtf5txEtXu2wh0RiVJ@rUaKf91mOjLDdR5/TyuQS7RXDhNeZQ42hPwN7W8hxYsy5u8RYhyzxzwV0XqP9kW8l@RuJRDsV7BHoFXFme5Di0bfpniC783UMXAiAXMxmTc26Pc9bp9SpCNFkX5N64A@5URkpoHxibbkv9ZKl2R7Mx@B5cbulym/oQXsaSJwC02J323YBqA0vhFn6O0q2xdGqYM1t5Ml3yjS9dX1Vxq9hfou7Y/7Y18EtBe8KDvwThfEyBL@0LeYP6pt0@IVSbSKaa5b7l0Hzl6pF3UDjBE5n85O@DmPb79g0DPcdKHbl3eB1gr6nkj2U3gN8mSbirzxFb62DUXm9S8BmYu9eCd/t9mjey0XBIgTNWvDWd95dZyVZFbj8daPvbtAnqENqcUcJjeGovlJDOdyMR6P202YmZB9PJYBzIbC@@pos83cstdJmLUYGFYUyPt78vzz@jJwSb@QKdJx6SAfH02seNsnv1bxhnjLzHp/zjymzp0@n/Pc@SBfkgEnBuUlMFdOgjJHcIKILyad@6qTMjPH@3sobNc0aW4iwiwC7dNPGJmTeLIL/Q/PrRTN3Aoz91s7aDntv/4DZ7kvjHmo5FzUYXgay8jlRpnzE2X1ySzXKj2tqgxyf0A4VhO0XoRK92XTpL4SDZA47LUAk5xuoRO3NkEtZyC4aSBFd0CF2aio66OtecNsNJMaTuFNqbAK3uWyKwXTyMVcJlciZ0x0P0wJZJbHm6y7lXkIITDZ0BQkVV6yRHI8Ws7gEGFY3iVFmeEtBETJf/0Hc@sXEkUkQihsF489Pw5KJFEfxvutLKssgGobyZbXFAvEhZgMk@EFGilApnkz3k2yEwbvSYMk@uwdWVSMuSubTbdJX550Is8ltHWUFAXXebp107sPPKZ@IecU/9/@lHJ/tvjm@M4Xo3WHl7RBki9Irg6TA5C8T3WSjvO1w6oW8pHBLiE7obL81VwojJvL3mGdY/caLHf8Cu@w4m10GQ0iyG9F1qF/wK0bozY7TerctTD1lq9tkBHk3gU6gYGQ6ZCDPRXQbiHKcr4mfyYnSFZ8LElHAnBnMkRCG9TzVMZejA4d7hhQOX60wKtny6A/GErh6pw/pUCno5DGcwryF7n/8WH1SOk2Vx4e1t8Fgmtgm6IB@PcU6jn5Wu7zuf868PPPOkwQHI4XZ9LcOoHuff65UWrk2510p9sGNr6YtTwrKNqc2asIJASqBFO3iSJhDxzghyby@tfVxgesN4gPFqDLRZ4z5BWYzCRoqA87xWKx1eFznJtBMw1rkl3aq0RLfQgiaak6soFb22pYp36o5ry2ACDmQZ9cgF61iQfB@XxCXeHqOMgUVMgHFcLgO4J3d6cqdpyK4U2Gf0L3wHSrGodQuKp7qNNAqK4msEW3CWMSebISL/9ElKswjnydcgT1NcoBmPha6QcFF9KlSreVf1v2QbEWzBuQnYQcOD3m12Aigh4UsISb7lOm3CiWq46tGEDvT8wNfUbaqzadXIq6OJJ4LEkCUswS9G3UKfAato46N4n0iJ9MSzooUo4DzTDaGEixgEb1431Lc/PSJ5OOM2CAfzfOeUkHgWD11FuXDVAcKzBx2Z/MzOcYDmPWiRMuZg889bt/@W9Mt7IHA8J/boUFCP8LM/wjhRj01jXGpHHHGsSWXqlB6jBamRWfM@uDOqEBAw1IogxTW3EOHFxihiBwk9h9ffd4XPc94Cc0AjATaT6k7HB5vPboQr4SlxSFxvexIgl@vPPFr6EdQFdi14nnBXLzA/1MRSPRME0Bkb6ljdAnmgh9qonQ7b4EESKWopr6acSSV1dXpEOHqQ6fiiZNRlLnzI8hx087Qs8BljBNgXsS8kCWfQ5Iu7ayuc4ZD@1GWVEvdNJO8jEJo7zZLjBQuHAAQNwoWrb44YCRSLFYBY0u82sDK9WNbeKAfSHjLXPedPa0EfkAkYkbeaO9lt39lgraaj6QZv9hMzj6CKyNwC4dp0Tn/kfywXiQHy2nRBIE5t@dECQZwn9xwlNxJz3ptz5yrtcebqg25A9tWUGbbAWglnQFqWCIoqPug57isFABvahf/AwooSdAz2J5caqoejqbL5XrjfYbHy8M6XwN5iSd11eeB5/fe/@4CzhfSb3N1EyBalczBZuVh1TtZ6sIYj9lfU3mqdJeU/pO6X1zP@tt2TjhTUF04FsR4/mur4BXdd5i36dSB4BZc739Taku9@eX@8er6wf57E3xP59yfz3zXyDhgtCDjp1fneQJnVOyd@k66NEC3W@7fAQde@funXuJeb@Pft/za/egwt7/y94PRN5fwWuYli4peSFJhP@dnUKou58yi8KuTyZhNr2ga2xSaUTqvkCWeLPbckgNadXl7TMVlsfMjkl1c3aI3VAZGSYGmsia0DpW0OYcEvtMwiyiZOwnHjCZQesReH61wXMJUBW73QtOxLtcjGa78uxS2vxc9HVsepDi2HtzgSJDXkoTqJskjpJM6n5N7jxevuTo5ddVSTRcyMNq7UdzNKiNy40qQF9JPHLQuko8Wt5gpO205cF@X40F8KuhqOR@Xpzj7VALpkZkbgHIQQx4sryYA5yALy0ejRI8WVN8kBn46LSJuIdSXFYd/HMuAqX7J/yaE8cw0rjcXlBJ39H03mOMcXtgPusEPWyy6gZtyxwy5ld5uR1wjLln/KLM8WsXcj@@fETcgXjnqr90uh1vZAC72ll@d9xrnztbWTCG1Wv3/mqvFEIisVMEx30nkfBPdAL5I4F1DyW2Da0CQRhDXcKcUUnXAjst6qSfxLeuB5fs1Q3NTfqu0Xi2ImXS48HzArjgBD@Jcwo4JEpovceF/PJdVAraGcXqMocuW1El72m//xHCuBA3eY6m9FkwN9Bk2E2AEQlZLjFaGIDh7xJRtIIZEKLIvJ7jYgk0H9cA6mQy7sjjCe6AwAtca/L6e3KvDfY90ORqInFptcaxOkyQIBZXJzQGoD2h5myLE/hrOZUA15ASA6gszPREUCg/3PKyDP3VBTIzh95JMgsQMs3ttZ/o8u6fN8AlnJkkFi0vFSD0@DmEvPOzpIA9c04l8bQy@QLj/k8PaOAXrKF/Q/0J5aeSn13nUmpDgTHmvnadT1K0J3Th8ZzLF65zGZkj33@PZqMv52DtPPkdfscagHznkjsJ8gzWUepcTp4zV65zLhW8wDng1uNxf4YMv@iU//M580Kdfw/WhBdiNLN3us51N@oOAb@ffgH6UA85p7wgM59dDtKxRu7kqPhz0eNBNPjPnxABv1APbQ8eVx7aFJ7/Ji0jlxrPbTVybKvsWuLNQ2YmA63oy51Gj2B/Q3O98skGPnwM4UTaKfvoD384o6Mw0/sUDbmUT8HQx4sz8uwHB3Xh0ByfH3LLpPOeEYL@58fGrNG4cz@4nGfZuoMOO6A2PybJC4o4oy4CP8co6qeffgLrk7y/9l/7H933PufjvWt9HYtdJL3R@IX3By/t9CbPSIkO0LTbFQy6KfKhTT7EGObCEw7@ICdFUVR1joOvMkEPxYAllkJS8gE@LrrhdEZCzvaPyM/206eP8If/4bO7Rb8fcYwVjUHefj66Sdfzmji7/rD@Yz4UTQcf0IwtFP34wweoMu/Bn8vLH/A8hnTE4g5F@QHBkpMzmo6QytmWHK15EkX50Ic4@4U420IafbaBPxp9cmdPZ2YJxNlPVz8RZ2Dsn11fP768eHz3/h89fv/To8fnubq/uvJfX6@vfY/X9/bM9okkzj4TZ@sX4izogNZ7uCDOUuurFibsPndtUuh5tsArEL7yPd6rjUo@3c57g1e@s2AhnfUG293MGQ13kf0tSgyh21Y@nat3O96gmeum1Mt3GxCvPz5d//CDxw/1@sF//XgPdHznufakDMMgh08XfvLLn6cTIfOWOMtdr7uU7wrIrVgxLVyO7wHuHtzherSOivyZOLs/u3d9Cn4KBqTAMkDP6FlVqe//63WIF9eBqaIFJoEJzQG/1wG@G9gENuvAXKnTHAR5@AvMISgGhHVgHJADMk0f4Xn/f15XqnUFUCmQzVgHDIQ1IMB1XK9XAZkABU/hTwwEEH3rwBL@AxJuevrHpwBJugMPD8Q96fiJh77kp53@gNMfdTrFx0hUff78Eow@3@ORNpJ4vOfXovHoIL3Op4f7RCLhfEyeUfrDA2WqF0cw7EgikJeXp6dcupN@eqLQwsP66tzzg8f3A3xS154r6/LpjLtGXPVffXwgnK5Vv99H3/5quTJDOGDG9XeJhzc4AJ/lO3mPA@vTcuBy3UceP7@43W6Y3D04k06zLi4XyYMF6XLQD@ugQAYdbmxaJkAv0yE0@kcj7uvraATuo3G3zxXAyWaWB4eqqg8OP56q@vFubyqV1jRmg4HCMDQ8OBjt6cFxH3xMpRIRHB3xJaKkovkSIbfD7f6Rvrqyygi6IdrhXDsUzUl@fjn8c31@uXLhjxv9ud0o0vq9drsg2R2Bu/Vn1/rKdeVCcRCFcn1@uUZBDPcZQvcu96P75cWMg1@X@8rEee0G7qH5@D/hv6KTuko6z17O0JAuk@GIG2b4vDscdcU9Cesv9REq4HKEnCGol8PJOO/vf7gIXcTC958eLx4vXFcX/ouH68cjJel2npEgzbb0pegzxDfizJ9sOeigw4mkMYnWtRWJ90sw3w4lksfi4HxyXbz@xOmE58Lzw/1FImGWfXHx80foOIAOCnPA5wwkmHSRV9dXO7Hao3Rfw/czaTEZwi@fQc7MNLAQXNYC9sPDOhDA8MlR6vzzGfOSxOjJF4czeSSwGL3LmcQ7G47PjnNGu6cfHS@O88@jF2RJXdBuPGBHwsnkRdgMx@JJGDjpCyslAClWEBJ4nWFxz4WhEkmTE1juhkqlRvxYhEFHPeKRJxKJUEH4XX8XzQfXRBLtAJjbDQ6fw@w/ZDyBEZ6Rup4gwFgfQcOvyFgAJmOSxGikIggfzXiYdZAjngfDj5cktHaGjHKwTSVuBRPBj8QZaBowSSEZPvMGwy94frVYrPjdJyvql8x0CnNK9Pn9b//mn8H3H@D7l@b1L//PRAT9/v63/@t/@N3f/h1E/mf4/j/w/U@//@2//lPzi@//Eb7/70HcP1rfAzjzSwCu/@n3v/2rv//9b//Fb@D7v1vf37z@/u6v/6P5/1@sPxT8u9/99T@iH/MGcP3NX/zuX/8ZkPjXKPzPIQz/VvSfW8GDWDP453YQ8v3bV8B/8fvf/qu/t8J/dghyEA9Z/xzi//Yg/s8JArXlRzIS83r9fj/8oKsXf/DVf/6jDUK/P8SekUQVLd8laHMzU0RZIKTxCbR9AzKwkvHu2Qg917hQ34@EC4pCQU0cT2DSsFJ2ALqug/oH5U4UQbbm6CEg9LSogexDmDcGCD@SxGAwEY/EE6Fg3BtPxMMROhqJeOmgl47FY4mAFyzDOB2NRxK0Nx5OhMLhcMJL0sFIIgbzCJkTBYoCs4Z2OEgcEGUWeeVfoccbFP/kmjjjeAEmZx/ItYtzfzjj7AhyEScdofhDgHRQFEw/J4x2sb5/TH12BENkkIyQNOnwOuokS54V8AfuntAdjNSBbADuSLgbSQw7g/Aahxc8BBUIzpkxev4bJazXT3Ws/OyLUl8rT2ZK3Ywyf@GuTj49OV6SBEW9ON4xi8y5rot0k5/RsO8idXHLQ9O5At4FDHSRT4u4IxpzXF7A1fHJEYLg2kUGnKC6HM4Hh8N9n3j85IhFHJdgM/uc39OfwDJNwPw3FnOAanMEgd8RhyNKBmMOxxC6Oz/2OclPjuQLsNdutx3jSbAP/H4SvmC9onQ1ZdLjciRcJNYLiQeHqTVNFeR0OZ2xoNPpdiYByUfysJ7uJKoc1M2smk2gA0gCAhMwyCc13lhosivhgyGI9CXcyReTpP/hgCZtBjNuRkOzXlzkJemIJhwoGkCuXAlc1nVkdHHppX3eHwhTIUZp4uyF4JCfdDhBJhNJZDvDQH11bVF3S25iY0/xgN4kce5EFDtD6@PehfdWSRIMUF9ICStn5@fnYLh3rh0hR93/dEVZhvc1hS3uh@ukJxXOerAN67ct/Gs0aXjzCYcJjUebnBw6F8I0heIRxJcxqZ8BuqTnj/n4odwUICWSaLR0nKmmRG7QpIV8MGm9@uUM20pk47O9ibWQ8YrcZRU1G3PZxk@j3D@S7l9qovQ5HvJd4/mrC5qJhIZ6aSd@jP0Y/7HarXfrhR8Cl/HL@MPDCRk/0392KxH6F7mcPLtUnaGwMwSGferMrC8dc59dB2N@ndmcPVreGa5wDOSHhHs8aAbpM6F/0iA9CJ24Xy3neFYEFMT/hBuPxeCfVH/6@ZyinE6SpM@jv/iuzP8r@MnWzaId0YjDjbxZ9B@ffnw6gwGRdAQjSLA9FGmOeYcDtGt9IeM//kLHfzy/j9Dh1r5D6bz7gqKouyAoyUQiGo@eEX@gqC8tQ0Pqbl1G4HlNX8xPLcykNbHKoEUrebc4A4HqYstrcLUPbbC1KYnUKVp5RPr0MM5SsQdR@KyT47iNTiFXExQL4xc6FQOfd0MKSFW4kLln4E1M8gKdNINcbNzEZ@ID4FqwBvZSgZ8kQXxAm7Lo1mXDecnvdcONNrcCbuLDB1M5ALBfN54QcpTJivTRSeKFQOxhOE4n0ZoZ3qsy/XIYtB2qqKZ3nrQhzUw6Vq7m0IBdalC5BwRfkIJJBdTmgsQlYspR5cziP5hgo4WASCmUKnnIQ6ZIAa@9Wrkd2gg9poyr91FwW4WTAYhCWBA45hQGR4CADiJdGLd7jpx/WBeG9JA0ShfwGi5AwUDpxZR4ScHKeI9uHyE7Qi@wkqIDYrN0l1kD8uLJKtaqg0UPrgSwENUO62kUYLQx67VaDz2vdv8IA5PtvuBCqeQVGXTvNtwtXNAY5nFAOCM750zBwc9/W2zG2OhHLzRt0twrd@3grJg9o16IC8M7T5pNpSaJWxfr/ozW@JK/zL//nv1RvZ8/Jt3zlIGuHs8cho2ZSzRBLozUPAXiod6Lj0nj3uMRH1Nz960L3cOIlAoAsGAyW3dbdYOayymgBe0D6G7v9l72/SI/egv3sgdIXngvhqmtl0kFvGv4iinaK3mfU7RVDyjTSG09cpK5gi9abjzyR4Ah1MMkj10UIMvMJaW298xjCvghQUaPpwCVATr1e8njeXRD4RIkvs2YlL7/nvFI1@uk5PO5EdSPoU@FewMCj54Uur90MVfrT9v7BeS/dME1BcVIbiAe8lm8ftnRDvQlgcdmm@5JN2lcI/LWQN48lboYfroYXqQ@ftzer33zR6/J/svAXhoQ8WtE/J5qEMOLoZt8xRI8BXM5vhMvv/Nf6GCYiR4PMNmrHuQ0KbwYQooK46BF9QvSl/iUEnspG0mY5ZtgPleOn4TFc3x8mIqOD5AyOOQkBXnTOiuKFrjp3aaKYO0yyIfSC5Mm2cdgCJRmnZqEEh/Wnz4RdtHWxjmUjJTLiCcZZDXjQzM0NCHEJ3DprCai06C@rF9PqWFb5@5M23ZpmCfBjA5FD7orVk24w@kae49AkBr4HHhJmhrLdJcAZYO1B8Bg7YHgfEiLICZZesKCTFmJyBS1GghyIT0hmD7d6EFqHeknUG/7ng8qxCQDOvMJMkTvNIV1E8iTCCFSvMLlQQC6CvEBKoFoQHUQH8lrUGTk99@T1u1VCqYGMTQWIDAEN/XQCOgNpVD4N1AKOBCVU5BRpA9xIUDbB5SCvHyOCgr/9xVkecq5IINn6jUd5vzBO4cXbRnppoMo4pvbJAO1xYcPU7AcLYLgH5vNkB/SXv5wZg33l2S2Xm10O/lWNd2GXzoYju8PZrrcHeHz5iwQFZ3xMRJl7NLCMi2aH5RZsF/ACASRUjh0QBdHlrsVmMLVcl70eAqwHjkc8nhAvdxh4nX80L/uV7QxtRJnInV8BB86TAl7z@DT/nz2yUqIHDw4S3u31b3Xqo5mrDCYWz71R2e7zXldt4448dlHvOFj7LAD7xz5oUIvtI5EwRuT9t4K3slDayFevD8Mk1oRn9s1MREc5cenVxhmdtw/CHSUCccYDJJoIhEPBC7JgBcFaDsQtAMhOxC2AxE7ELUDMTsQtwMJK0DbmGkTMx2Mh0LRfTC2D8b3wcQuGA7sg3sM4eA@GNoHw/tgZB/clxbelRaNY7zkmc1N3HV5DaXR4bidhrzOZQNHRgAN/ToyDIQG30BC9vCbSCgvfhwZSwSsgkpUHQEFg9H9PWgfGzblMqnymnR4zZLNOysSxirCnPRggc1rGmil/BodtARC574kkVshQYDaJVmJZ8AY4A2wUlIFkH/efWm6p2uby90gxSMMKXp3D9l5mKlCHhqfGWaKz4nk4KlkE1vwJDbTvZ/cMebAr9Ii0qTy8thjEmMMH8UdYv2IFCzi6DsQQRMCtcGeSumgzI62OFlk6MtFHiE8WeQboky8kVO5EG9cGHnKzorHf4wtZZdn2ik8bm0wA6wDIrEMvGpQ9JxC6jN96fj9b3/zf5C//@1f/R35u7/9u//vP/0vKPwf0c//BTYLGdwB/OVfoZ9/i37@N/Tzt@jnrw8yYfjQpeN3v/l3cPs//3vyd//sr8ykf/X3Dm94hwhSUNQ@59/8c/TzZ@jn/3Z4IzvAv/kLExBlcXhfiCPTygVQf/mfSRJKQ1h2yH7zDyTp8ICB4bIk797s449u9ysEOzbc49Dj63Tzl51oiO0Bt8cBeK07en/nQQ3gPkCuMejEw33fA3PGdOdBWppl2AlynbWiFB3ZPywyYRTdPwZ5W3Fg9FiLBk6o/f9IXpJOD4KBaPx4RsrU4Vb9rXo79qkI1uOggDp0LpGFCoXdO0pgekuAfOOZwEb3o2kLnpHSpoxY/K2hE1XtAcRhS5ZouGg3YZVl54ZJD2kdTAf/@6kuElo0DJmPN@ADIgnLC5Q@KPBI3bxqNijldQxMGfdO2IdZcQQ/V6FJINuO34ix6AZzwfsa3b7lrG6TrxdedRj0GYGJOTvUSLuCUqTD8RVYxGkL3o0srtAxvEmvBXAfuAw9Eofu4KeAHXd3dw7iIC6AZEjjXBjDQaVMlbFLoo@TggdJwYMkoNnEiXVNJBh8RQMeOJBedL92gD9WUcfZ9sKFeo7dDogMmAua64NeQVrok9Rb1FgjHyu7t8gPUNKPKaufPMhY51yTDvebDIDzOE/qdVueRh14A/O2oU7nRNw@ijlqrfcxHeU56BSYe8RrLu1ajk6carnjAr@Amn70fGNBwcB/Z0G@bywoGvl6Qa@bFeU9Qv8@f7@udmw1sdPwe2Rmxz87GqDQ0PgbEL29OkIUazjocsOUJ21NeUYrhXSdONQQ4in7@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@9qI/6KzKPN/Tdyj3f8U2biCZq0pZecBd9votwTx0vMhudcFqT3AK9d4xbPcFhffVvFkaLDSk8xT4h1Bbz0kSmGnzPAQJfviAzjXbrd74uVCSLupAdvxmEKS@/zDy/cvVbNaBE0Ze6BKBpo0DP8fC9@qlrdqBvz2STJPEXe0qPm@GO2ZA09svVVhgAfzDPCae@@WPeX1GfLtavSN4wIO1j/cZXR4wc2RvQAwNs2/HUs@npN8SrDLlPKbuUj6@S9Fhe/1OIHUmHLpGmVfJtIfk3ovlnmDkTNRLZXYdlfN4S8wZxlJIllXYcYzZgvtpgiv9EJKA61mCK/M6o8nVCou5xY0xnofMKUaV@4CRGCJbgu4dqDK0IIc9AnU6DsuiG71l7ywilzRj2wWqyYexbZogdcdB/uIx5AEXYYLeS@7Mpk3y2TfVMme1TmrgccF3kARLBHRVqtgJrnS00g8YLxjnZGSWjmDpcvqW34yAqjob3Xz07ReSl6SefSeQkK2ck7L/MuUMpOznmZwwHdednGgZnz8hYC@77l/Nl5aXcLBKDBLQ78gOItFY7uWedl1uV@IfC7Q@xy/c7LXZsCzCfzFnPkxVxeHVm7/spuVZXnvaZR6SWRxOhwUVC17h@9@BuAfwxqHZoBiR9TZPACA6MJyNGgcTBimOXAsOHHLydwnRo@Lu2lKWt9Y7@GAume1MGiCpKSBdZHzjPnsTIyCUOpePERrkAg0puXpyki6Tczs6@RY5UOEoob@bh8zD0/tgc4F06/B@DDRRxpn99ur2MUZgN@G50o83t0viHHLg5ThJwB3CfIQkz9yfmFSqG2PqbFav3DFnq7RoAa0WeDmK2E0R7odLDhkG2KC1MV9VhIcCra7RMP86CP1SmR9L7KhrWC1TPfScbRVs2QYjjs/O4vVecgHyLtSAWhxPvAo9nLduMC1sUoaa/rDixVs/MBCQc6h8MPb/JIbHNWEMOZ6saLx4r3hiE7r1kk1lzHahIy@5Hz/oIxzNL3@zLIpf/XTV/tnGCCA40IwUHOXSmmflV@hf2umPa7bVDbTHhVwCnD@vRQ@ta8/uIo@4pyaV/s2wZEiV4y5z5pHO1K2LMcZgcHlvmXZO2NiY8OrDaNfLPQHfZX1r7Ntt2c4Ct8ez23MHEhK0FbHkfO0MLsLPg@o95aJNLSbxstflSShces@I7SfdW@TKtZ8VNNjFLQGA2XX93A2nEDHzYewocroL1iudnL0Qs08D7Frm@jNfWDnQtz10FBXmK7o1EOIkHdY/@1nYsWRNSfWrl6rTKAQTcWi7nfbkWgXgt59@M48cVtgt20JehFD6/jd3Ah34mJohkfH2THW5cyHAHGAIP3bUzxs/q429JlB/r8Vd@FfCbsAUctXLN9N2COtBIydRg0ZIsWXw1gCG@4LhgLiW3eAr@9eLaGdo2QdKANnacnPHw9PSHnnKcnaxRDTbPbRvrDmf3OhYMXaZ0dezO98xpCtACwmJuvcbIW4KxnP00/lDP0yrTdSwx3uRayIdrODmh9CG1R7TwjXCHabb5pzY4xX4gGkuoKhtEUNhhBz0KZuRA0WvjErpVWOR9NQwedK6arimy9MW1mvlUPn3Km20uvmOyFvGKwG4hZCn6E64Ai0yHL3hfDL0HCh9uZb5xiZHMJ2eaNl@THfrzjE0zAlGMmqubZJjvXD92NM2GCsY8W8Hgk8XP0IiKQ3ROryVURWmVSEMdjECTKOijQdHDpoHcT@RTBl92/GLKHXydlnfZk@YTh49CsdWBgp@vooWudDEbBmkp4gbP7LzAWucmQ6MHqAHbSwlDwjcElZgbj3oO8H10b9/GVtj9uhO@j6wm17M/mSAGtI4HIywd8xp@fD5emrU1LrAcOdi7t8wMI67yHFN6n9CMfNdXlOHPYpyqgoOk2wUis/TiyCz0If0l8kLHiQR5gJGv61oCBKyOjDW@vuXcuqTL5HRkK4heYQHnYSsXFAg5zZ@8IO6RBVkSs6d1nKRjHd5zjO7SZSHw4Q7rQlDWU3xZlFMbnPu1lmfxooTM3VFBXNruAfRM5uAnBVOPDiYI/uhwewOJxuB1HmADe2v34YGret1lBKbr/QHW4aL@gpNPpzpzWWjfpcXqSbg3gPhOoePrTcJ6i8kWJS@dKo82NEusshWCgM2hmRiFPI8atVbE4zxbVPCGGB3PPMLROFMPbSDaUTbOBO@GmIoRj2TvhTufTEp@gltNZk@Nb6ojWdPG2Vq21tlSh2@yNm1Nh2O9PY3KbUFvDzLi55pvxvrzsdRMlvcn3sjVjVpsaC3pTj/Wj3ZWsZ3qdzKS8Ka1m61JUGYiRbJOP9QS1uGI3EZUtdonhsjOJtoubWYKec5t0VucGMY@HGmQz43iR5YZCuZ295cZaZBSZtRNMaDkvC@pmcluUnyvTbHvJetRpoRRdEnKjtFzx4f5sJBXlYavXG@UyjdWM1ocqNw33qwtjFNeiodAizU@m4UhpYWjxSiZ9GzNy6VKvIN31jOGmF28QRtHoxLplNiF5lnWDDS1yXUoP9NZl8ba9ihaDHaUol6XStDG7Wdw0JHUxy4XFemce1sZ3hZESDBab7WVxUCG0cLk/iLemwXiOXbPUbURR5qFOolbRqutF5rnO97NsO8OPooFM5C5PT6v1DVtfVlqtfkPtd@cx/ZaWhoXAlKjfse10ZlaozON0p7YpxW9K7UU2W1ovR0FhrKQXXD9UvYuuKjW@1G9SoSKzMKoeMVuXqGm5rG963dvSXU0fQreulsWwsFlnehlNeM5l9WqrQtW02aQdnsqc2ouJWYUtN0phozRLF1f9YaKUmfFCYzRTZp2@1F8YYm5KFYhNdtbsjvhVQdyumHy40mtS03yLNWLpcahNTQVhNJPq@nZ8U9mO24vRmEvUbwI5/vmWy/QirbxKVwt6uCZviEEnI4jbVlOgZ41EsTQc5dNiVY5kG7zauCku18HgQBQaq8iWXt9NC2FxzYYDlXrmrupploMtT8WTyTSUUH1MBHOFm/44cutRCvyWqgjMcyzr0RaL8Dq3QG@zqnRlSZtHpEC80PFMYrrWT1Srq5Feumtl@6y0jQ@rs1l02CLuliVd0YLxciGdoBqzgHbDTGulYUyUC@FV5kbKJ0r9bTdu5CsLKV6sjHPllpbrzNm7RH7c3mxm43iZb1RmaYKP51qt6WjcG60Hbb2xCVTD7HTkyd/ka89j6Me9diFY7mai40Ur1LvNyctGp@DZKnf9ipqtzeh8I76IdmKhObFcl@PptiGLau6mmog2F2Iln86Nu1la4fm7Z/aWnjHtziYQ12Nas3DXVHWP0Rkp4dEkE9o0qwOqN9T1SFEkhut@tJSeaewttzbKeqwjB5V6M0A3hVpXiiz74vOgoUzTc@q2e7elRqttYd0wWKM9UyJcLDK7WevP2vZWuyXigykjdWtZpTJlo7cDcRujIrTcGWSFKjsoBwPp7rhY5QvF5Xjb5efBafF5UWQZVm@kB6MbKbpcqx4hFF9WiE6tfzeOPT8HRnxtkBDTs26rUTKCHYZaDNqVyHNloOsFtlsSM2FRXuQyg5vZPDvcMB19vV10oiNJ2DS0YCBPrGuDao@dKmO9oA/Z6fauMJSri2D0rj4VYgY3o@ciXekJgVhNbXlynoZ0Mxpvor0Fv2TBMlSbJZXOpKfTOlGn57FlZpPQDflGv62NsuW0mE5X4sGmGowVZ9mb4poTe91ercgxSng4yoai9dE4EOQytfy4EZ6PY41aLFzJEp3RptmiuVxcpCeMlJ2WN2E1UQlmolRv1So2p52JXJOy6f5ayITYjrKK9RlB7vLbaIyqBjzTSaIspwPhRpToGjmjWymsQh75tlQNNjYb9m7ELEKM8DzQPexgO9nWezyjSJPKc4vu9BaVrDid9qIZthOoZ9qBxVZfMWqlQSRyDZnOVdbLwmrS7gd0NVdU46N1jcs2GvxI5UKqMKqn10Jg2e8Pm81uXZ7fNefFVmxU33LMNNIzhFa0vjaIZzB5estKtzBa5wRdmLaWz/LNenHXo8Ldm3mlyy0908RwsAyJd/VApZbpCcyi1BzHjG5trVbLkiBR82B9TBGrbmO7Nfi0kq@tqoO10Ntu02JGf6bXtxRTuSnl7gxPIl9I5@qdNqNJ9fpNJZdm5qvqqnIX8/DbdpWLiLPnIdGQZSmoDdtSLBMI6cFuJLfNstObwOImM@@UOwlapbvFXrV6S08kds7GBvVctF9l@@l0@XZTFpheo6E2brsdou6R74bDDlXvSJWEUCm1OkqktNSq/X6MWSnpJhMoheejVWWdWVUXi/48UfYMDJ4JKVuep1srqULxRZCdOMEvlo1sraFvgs/b6fN4mVPueom0ehNNZzcCt@SX20A6t/RQemG94qKiGg92BusbYcBWx@PbVmYSUpdqJ5qNEOWEUJV7o@ykmtjwt8VKr7Aw@DY3CosePaBOO810V@@yG/GGjU6WXX0gQecT1Egnk03o0jAXv9VETyDOZgi2X2UaVGUSuauVOWWVXVd7mxxMOeK00AhElI3cW8RncvFWz9z2n2/j8XF3VJxBwYvJcMKKXU@GG/FNQaoRw7vb3izfWPSoafOuGmt0i574NqTdPLPK5IZJbDrbeiDAC4nxsrRYh9QKG7@J39ZZqbyutboCP462g03pRt4SOTk2CaQFerVcyZRnE8nE82Mh063JWq7LFmO80mAoat0fGvX@Xfw2eBNoBtrzVSCoV1dUQBjI4mZQGwyCHJFZ6rdqv00v856ikR60py32RqJq/VZpq2wq@aDeTdeywu1itVErG1ELDdnKTVZqsCINZkkkOu5o3dk2sxwRfWFdyWbisWGwCBKk61JiNQgzPKur4/WUqlQXRWk9Xcx6mme@plqe4WAdSUx6E51iK5VOrbTKaxGlrE9lIhplg8W@psb01vN8U8oauUmvK4Wzid54VC8OqGpHuE00s@1hjI80qNIzn@i3owG2EumzFN1S5ksDRiR2PCMqmwCnsRKvMbFF/TmSXyw83Ga5MDzqMHZzG@@PZ1l6yTKeUHqkPDPrXlkKiLUYP9br/dXyrtAHC1HuLbsyURh21dCtWBTaxV69OqMb6dbWoDKJPnsXHg80WpCFZStkRMolfhxjhVx@OJvmiqXnUmAgPAdWtKQ1m6FCkSZigidjKJxE9ZpqU94GGT49qMerK26bnU9qAl8sBXPaoBXl2reMlIdhVHyuBNRe4aYy5EbShBIUud5uBQLEMBrM9@9az/SSaza2HWVd1MbldEMK3QklWWnc9ehcU6NqsUyhmZ22htlNPNrQpBHfGcc78txzE1JYJi1XokSMX/KZXp/q8mKIjq23I2bGU/SwP5vFi9Q2qm@ptKyvpvHxNjG6mdP9YU256Wxm1M18PWxk7ugF76HpBqsSTWPbiNzc9D23m5tuaSx1SwJLMfPNVC9mFnx5NWpG0564Guh48lxvsq40xmo/T8VGozjdDoX6YeOZa2z0Zo3o5SrFUCy3MdZCfraoreNFNR1tb9bdZjg8G07X9Xg72oqs6aUyy2fUwjhCKXd6TF53iuNChs8LVUGvbkfsnIhuF7VSIZ73RHhm0BgMA0Keem5zkjEZC53bu1A7SrGRYr2xGg5zaWoeE6b5knQDY@KKqa437elgNmrW9ZBIKPWBpxTdRrftYbPGyY1@uToZrcaxWEMr9qaJxXagtsSWR912SyPlJteYS7ntHQhctJWITLtSvtsX73KtQJ0wov30CmxwOlMRN2OqFAncCnKgvJ7fJO7m/ehsMOtll63BejaNtmMRZcFvY0b/ObLgu7FBed6m2NFgNfEEbwilvd3c5ZthrVJbqRWjofC3gXiwMpx15/lF1zPP3hZGRrYfUEfBfmW18GQjYBXEq71EsDa6nWZKs5umXmwGE0SnIG4W8elN9MbTgMFkMdXr8Z4UlJZUn5J6qyU/mweYWo7paetRt1DhalwwTqkeMbYybqPP5UFjyBhqWKYIfRPlVoynmAcLIicOIm1Pz1ADc5iLBO6WoVt5HArq8l27zRpZJTbrhhJ8uKD1ZKW3Vqa9oNi8ic1WrHg7JTL8lgtL3Vafq623Ky4xC3NMe9lNF@7kfigrq5O1rtHRxG2wxzw35lqobqiNSpfNyM05wwgrz1rK5Kpae0lw41qa6xeeF8KyF66nw@nNHRcIL4bLKS1v7/KD4LQxSk@EVasf3rZWoQx3Q8utuajOtSAV6PTk/Cy@7hb5W6K8zfObSbyZafTC3dtpYhaSxrN2I7CZ1UWBHQ71BV0ajCtNmitFeplmYlYU9DQf6yaE8pRa10b1YTTL8eEA4ZmU5lQwW2FD5fydxyizUuRZ3NI1Y5sQ5E2tK47a42VarXDT7qKWKVIZOri8WdfnoWKLCi2YzDyeu9UGmkTw@Uh63a1Xo/pkmDZ6YaURXMbVYUMc3wW5xoRh54FoHHRwlRsNN910K7OqDGrFtp6Wx1veo61u5ZtSoZCRiaLQrz3rz4wiLNLhbr0yaD4309q4ExkZeoleP/PUZiPXy1mW3QzSJX1W65XbcikWmHOZaqw54SpyV2mIoVuCTcRmdzFKbrPlRYAPN9LhwnPvhn0uLaMtZSYbbCc/pI1aC5RdKdKtq4PVfJudBIR1KJy/0@tjTh1Cb51uieCi2BpwLWEqr1etstG7Dc3b9Ky3kmZRmVE94XyiXmfocQhNwiJ3ijxXpNuxcdeuLW81ippsowteveFvRaISVMfpUitaDjI3N4NcokvPnyt8MF4NL9KrYL1V9cgRXs2VxnMpkJ21pnxThClDP9qYlgPtmtgdDxfZu8SmTWwHIyEhl/sr5TY7W@Vmy2mnuw7B9KrTq@h6u3VncKVlcFSOSaP6hOvkCtkmm2UYPVaXs/n6TF30RvNVMRwhpoXQ3bQaK4vj6CxW4jeD24WaaJS3peykGPYM5HLcGDCG9FyXps@1kWGMnmNir90sU/1MjJUDz5uYcTfpUzpRjM/zN2E@ti1N6FhXni8XC67ekpXSptGsAptjwVDnZkSl1X6zYfS4Is/eFbtg6ZcVvtS@K6vtm7sit@BkQgqB@GYp7famohfucrMhvSq1NiOR9szqt6t6JBYREiPPMjKvTRa5SKQfm5dry0JO1aLrKmj9cWPTqPCtWpWg59VBfuYpCzQd16rb3jLcSvN30VF1JazCkVx6LU/i8W5g3SzfsM34SC2t5t0yPW5Sq2Fips@ZLtNKs4pQJzLPamiTWxv5QCR/Gy3eNflpdMXlF8FSetXul6JGoib0@@HnVWs142sFWuisl6tgo1BvGnI4su41h7NbaIUIwY7XzXyMr4Z5LiBuh1mtoIzkLpMOUGUquOr2mh5lLD/XeM@sESyE1Gg@sG4wMDMeZhZlLjrqTqX@TaaYmBBcmM17Onq0NIw@3z1XRe1u6onNQeXEhdayWQWTZGR0O@F1U0gM6G0vG@8zo8KWzt9S6XCxuEiUgsFyJVEZEHo7MgdpeV4F78o5Kdhs9DrhhSdXy625SXvYbWVX1fhwQM8b/fayjCZjISqwEurTVndTK6y7Ih/Nz1p5IUN4Ss2VXk@oQivXy2tUgxMK4emseFO44Re37GKdlz2Bcam7WT4v5ny8XJUYXpMLLWOSZkOD@Cy0Zktq@vm2R2yKTL5MZ@O9uDYT2fK01tWn@rKvCmI6/BxZe4zWtCHeRnKtzp087U5qNY3NVoMxnc/N2vPosDtdj5Z8nisTgpFYstL6phY15MymIN51q80y1w5s2Ea8XCto68CIKjy3A0uD6sbbjc54VNPEyhQGTs@gqyhxCVSKMVGaBKNOSoFVL33Lxcd69iYQr5TX9a5Y8wSa@dY0F9SXmoeazOvB3FbJl0PCKjZuNW/nAS275Cae20aMGk4zyqpGRAwu1Gf0WaIl0INBj1Lzra2uV@Pdkee2KVF8KziMZYpbujMKqdxiMogP5jfL58Gg@jzqtYvQnHcePtquPhPj5m1RjwkJlua6mWwlrSzVQFmbt4TwvKIMusGB4Bmsc6XVc/A2UJiWRnStNtluM2xZ68vx3HxUzTKbaTfeI0L5eoAbhni13M09DwqTxZTNVtZs6E4p6p67cG29uNHisSgdTiwZPdSbz3ueeFoSPbHQZDMJZvLLaI7itFafyNc92b6iQC9oDaNMjdLDXE0y9G6s084nWtlCtli5zd8JlUS7xNzdeQbNUjaf7kTLt5NZ@HZA6xkqU51M20FiWsnOOMow4guxLRb0/I2WW0@Gs@Z8MVrFlhV9sJVvmYU4ntMCo876FTkWTTd7z5F6IJSvUvnhVpKDscg6QXCswJUpqTW768fFfJEaSBOYQOdA/md31YXGCpo@SfSh5tWtHMt26@OeVpQmDaBQGi1UVpgnxNmEDw2JFtWOF2J96VZg64PWPDYYiXedcigmLNYwfx3ktrdCjoJW7w7ak0XgLpoH0zUcfi71J/PmstbTW5Fcr1NphInecysn0KV8pdIbGhxdqwfGhaXRjcWLeZqdZ2a1/CYzypRWBbbbL3qmnmCHY5eFXlrK9zhGX2@GgURASwtTIjqNVjNCjjZWkZ6ghbPlST3ESCVlXS/H1XmrUQ5myvmmoMy0QKaZtj/R3iYxFyObsZBO3/RKg@yYSDezuWmwJ@hsS/asShgsU5CYP/zqo0J4TZMxGLFURM58H7t1zEXyCwdP4JMn0OPtR@dOIGefw4MEBOv5aqAFyvE6uugJ4Uvr1e9oT9KPjh9GW4vJ13uLPto@TgBf0Dke5AU@clg42gh1aCjzjoyPovwlAvCOJ95BQftg@PHk7/RL@AINXhslsAk/UefCvHF/lTbMEXTOB43OqXpMHmx5uuhDahCB0GSMLAA/vY7v0KkK30NGvAWcrxfcp7b1A8mj/ECcrsr4pBGHz@/AWa1TMRCmYxRma6L43dkMBD6Qxd5Y@8ILFRiKjgeiCXy@Byl7De/8PvHovWBTDpI3REae6wttxc3GymQpkBKpTkdrdrN9JslImAxBWcHvSQ8qk46mKHw8Xwx@42QiYJ3UhD@f8Emj6LgqfHIaOrfVSZK@3WlPH0k3DnjRz6Uj@UZKyYu5LYXmIR/z@@hjSk4FkvN7@TEpezxuw5MyPLTHhSK@p91JdWF5It4bj/ipfeqCrNqP1h@8m76hyOwEva8ev/vr8JkTfCiX3YHmjHrYn5Y8ayjaYYyA5ImZH3XEt1Fol5h5lVNUbDhjo/Jo6253KoGEXoqIfj4souHk23RUww8f0BEaSct34rACnwl1MZJE9pL4gPmJtsDR4/SXl9ahMCw67AxtoKE40Yw0aSFF3YWSk3Yqq6gbK7NogjzZdbk6QHntQnurbu@3QNpQI/R6e/RyCA3ATBCTvUfgJKDGW6NukyoUrvDybh8UnePjTqJTTsiPdpp94g@CR3KDz915MkgRn9IDlyvSAsVnYJBu68QJHHsvoofesCvBtdNM@jBdzFW8/@w36bU4gl4n9aQyorbL6dcX6O3RLpJGzBBtolELoMALOhptyRj8YdPYbYEc3/DDV6g@CF8DH18OBLOMpm2QbkQPHyB8nILzfDDfV@YiDcV0rDTJsPLiaritpgbGocMznarzksR@cEmIwluiyYPUKaSiur6TPIfkOWNM3kmeINwL/b1kDZLRW8zeSRYh2Xwm8nS6AunmTv87AAby8gRxfTKUJ4MRJZd5oAc6CuTFVNgu0uOxGbsTAdJsGLM9jvOT1tEo5EezdUxhOxIv6J9YrEwAJNIuq/Og@7204FR0tqjLlIuDMk2ekJ/JrxZmOUcCi59wSaB2UfnuiyP85AEB0P9AlZJv0@3CzdbeVfRIfvww7IxRawOzQuTPP3@JMksQj@WPfrSlz2wh5Id7UEOTW3s85mue9u1qZtpamU7nsY6OOdRuto/Evh52pwzuVYjZt/b9WhBlDsoAxB8Po5HLk5v8tI@51x/Jy5322PPR7BZf52PwjfQgjyjcI73kaB9kv52rDJJ7yMnAiDzaKwt0ThiTfMNOfQftO4a@BugdN1/JGXskM1Yv/bWV/bbanAF9uFNj3iRNRcuCaXhtEXiCPMZs10OdYCI7d16a8ejtVeIxMvEdZOZ5ek@AwLgCGtDIZqtxe0wUZb/5TCro@UAw7MUu5ibIy55NtrL6Fj79E3QuxDhryF6gF3ocqyTyBGvegO/qjfh1/brLvaqeqelPV@7efKjZ@cmJaCTfyhOWuk8wSl6SAXJ3cFOSfPm6HvrjOPN533xH9o7uel9X2I1uS@K3iODLO4z@qpAdVyH4SB5xfIHfw6t@dUjChxCeHpT2rvVPdoztdmn27XctMERV8jgd0WwitBPAUD7M5bVsruu96rROX3wybOPGu7fC8KufsVSAyZ4kDtU5ms4V8OB9GLs7Ogpz5DAFPcmOLEzNpkwUbNsWzGA7n599Qs1sMhnxE/r0WFE4l20wWQYDxmCf0AFAXvM4q51ZZZqX@@KhOMvoJcfWKR/2uJuEmI9WFB5Xkvit9rZ9hoi4GONuk0Td5sC@EXX8mjecjkYjKMp@@gA5K5rah7x8HY@gdybQh5OZbI2PziTDJ1daeh6PxEfqwZFlZOQYiprDnFpfOVD8riEQzDVMtPfnW@I2eDmxymCe4Wmdbvn5cOoiJkU/sol3jW57QbqTO2qurhyomJ3Av/z/)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)

### Explanation

The stones program looks like this

```
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
```

Since its made mostly of words I put it with the other word soup programs.

#### Grass

Since new `w`s were added I needed to remove some from later in the grass program to correct the error.

#### Alphuck

Since 4 new `p`s were added they needed to be balanced with `s`s.  I added `sss` after the code and removed one earlier balancing `p`.

#### Cubix

The Cubix capsule needed to be moved again, nothing fancy.

#### Paintfuck

The addition of paintfuck's directional characters caused the output to be offset improperly.  In order to remedy this I shifted the Grass code forward until three `w`s were in the paintfuck code reseting the location of the paint brush

#### Golfs

I noticed that Moorhens tokenizes `and` as a increment so I added spaces to the python/ruby code to tokenize those `and`s allowing us to remove four `no`s from the Moorhens code.

Comment: Paintfuck is broken

Comment: @Potato44 Fixed now

Answer (score 6):

## 118. [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), 4115 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#z bxe xxxx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[        _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx@O6O4/x0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 2 5 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","xxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","xxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __"};
//}"                      _
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002504 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4219 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB/2CRWlvkuIFBO@URK3Fq0SJN5EiKeqytUEQIEGCAASA17V1oufFdvc4Zjztno5229PH3WFHdMTMkycmwhPuiImwX/0V5wfm/MGZzALAi0SttXZ3UyJRqMrKysrKysqqShR6nDH8wx8O8EPXVXk5kFWTNgXDpPu6NBP0IJ1d0p85yYiFIxSFUBl9MJ0IimkcUwc0S0sKL/XhljbVsaBIK0GH6DCt6epA5ya0OeRMWjB4ThMMWp2a2tSkVXF/rghdmKgjKYAZJ5IyAChT0DVdMElylG4pMjfp9blXCbHd0jQdkg06L8i/TH4xaV6dTDilbwBgnM7XsoVy5lX@BF1RdUNALLxgGCrGJen/@h8WBYF/BZqiK5wuqeVM9XwnxWJNXVf7Ux4pN4cCpGNlRUkWDIoHus5ozWZwEAP0Aa0LXN8Co0RVpzELPRnLtETzmkb3ZG4Y5GlZAthiKEkLyBx6BekHtKFOhG0CDFoRhD5taAIviRJPSqWFhSkohqQqRpCW@DE9l2SZ7gsyZNiQwvsBGT01tqKsgoNUX6Vo@PDaK8LXd4cCwCiCU3lBA95g5VVkJXDC4cFc5zQNiAQGNoFwU5qAMEim26AFzpBQ2CCLISh9wjdtLYYqzSnbtaRnEkdzQO9UJ7gNQTehekGClx4KugAoubU0eOa6ZAILkK0Zui5wOn2jC4J3Vyh3ioTCVCzBxIoESbOdnroLtaIbms/KEeQ0kzrQIzfXlxRHB9P04dMJfNMu1wlVqObpL4cPGLbEEJpY0z2cl07/hjaYhwcBvgu2xwz0FwqwUsAVmWZUzWS4gAYEBkwgkOEwiKHALBzU5K2C6dNXbbElVBZUH1qDLil0209qxk91HfvZhqncGCotq8oA@AmV1acK8kOh4yFoAl6FnuKnhRlwTVWsNlLnhMM3QwkazcAm4XrAII5H3lu6gjAUtAXIns1Rp1xDlacEDnIaJgogcAWyIsaSSLdpkZNkzALpiMqiWheMqWxinqnSx5YHdSD0g7RDBq/2EWiizqA4DpCSCOhDk62eR4gCYGgIlVQVk373r/5tfzAAPBmeV/W@La5tuq/yRKtxhFjQFzQKrKpwMiEL4PxYupUdCphxstTnTCxeWdpFECJIqXN1KvdpFQrU5xJ0rSE3g@4oigJvCpaQW6rQT0@4saUvJEtyoeITrgcNSwogZZNqB@jPOWglXqAOiMwEJlNTTNIBrUC7DeYnz6djz6ePDwIQ5w16jw4ZZnACAhc8IlFw5/6a5LQzmwaFsgyTM1SpT2lLc6gqYTrA0y4@rWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q2iHvN4T6Q0HxQlpe9xg4xnoVy394RP8/fS8ePJq9zbJQKWOWLB3ip4eK@LAo1D@sSMmXCSEtSWdDtgh7bSVOMJOY7Jwa1o5MvruJkVcUAGAxRLFeUD1FDQkAVB84SCrBe1BMLtrTYm7KvoKxx2hY@lR5/7wO3brjrBADXdqSj21RtJRa0la8Mp6GhgimJooL11FF2eA@ExUImbMBj76R4Ra6L5QbEQlTgX3LpA90CPOmJEeqTV4zB/APWkjWHTgxy43Q4t9Lf6M@gC6NKm8UYpy@ocCia04bAFGkTBwrkBNBFktiqUsSpklUhidqs2VkCvILaeQCcDPQn6AvY6UO226G/VEcAjYQsGsFl9ZUsFTbglYOGtIXHTb2hJhC41AS2hL2leQNUDOkiwxhUsZEq6oQGGCJokoUA4Ftvtam96mqkzmcAd6OoV89UOhZXf7lOob2hRmNMypwym3ABtIQWycDwvaKatr6Amhgka6fWwQyID9hgaNIbU4efXZZOxxB5dt8pAXW@1nj0icqhkbIMoIINOpTnbmqP7kg7aSV6@Lh0AZq8Kd/2MIDsE/Ox6hwTHEAAhExYCPzVBuYEgz4cSPwTZReoUSz1aY9Hr4iFqu3RQ8AFxXTQSw579GKaCzDoKyXgXRQBb9C0eGGMR1dlOBGn87YivY@aMyR7E6ppEGA@2YoMMFwTZs5kG1lMTLTcYbBxTifSstTm35icwGLo6dFMQlqFpasYx6HbJHE57QWhW5kZflsyagi3LmPpSMlUr3JPVHuhSAzoT45TA8NOetHhVIxK3ZvjIoGZgNIkGnYbR9nkKIuJxiwZoORKfQ@CtJBfRtgSF9esCQAIUBE55RIPozyJogOZS4T2uIJH7IPQQl592YS9zeSGAudZ8yakTVBl0hwzmaJ1ldVAzIqgWW1ETPc3tHZ7WCpvYYm53cKRKiueL@@PHj@5j9xmo448fP0HoFEOfMOSD0CcSCpAQwgUxRHL4SQhT70kOjHt0v9w7mBfeR2y2BQ4lK0nzcPfHx5FHP3fP2tcwXr2gl0ANAXQAL4DH7U2nMej1us7mUNFgT7Rq37A42yfS0BCUASUsNFU36WotX3iqZ24u0i5mauiMLPUYBQbDpwl0N5hwuPbkh5mDkx2CDVU106TBMJ5AFwHInjVRpjqFDgqTBWkimSUyRZEVFO1NozmpOSjXQlDanpCIujpZqxeDEvihSrsOIy40pHemeTjm2qlRTJ3as7yt@ATGT3CSFuSpAc/TAdW6XUfagEkExHlbEGZQ1MDnQ0gyj1tH2pApghInc0G9Z5G/Z3JoA8cRuK/2BHkRjwYEWQyai1UQe2I8SlkXOtB/D2JPXmqx2peBMqFbBRbiqwTOmWDegC4vg@lOlyWDzKO3OU6tZe@Bcll9I7KrpV2blPDGpNpvB7q2sRA5gbYaq6iJNqEnMHpiOyhg@vo2pygZQ/KzA/qGorcpJLcx6YnkZw/AsW1bgKGCE11kySVOk9C8UVWYFM8J2ERVVIsUYJWkcEyDXIIwJO2jZ1fz7xDTE8QpTJ2YnqRg@BtggVSSQIq9nvQeKPAFSXeue8D0aW8f20C4hm@MA3qH8eZUN2Whb1//@x/3oQHeNs@QW4LJz4/XgSfgGzZVQHy3teyseEN@9rcsgRlNZYkjbCChb6HkOZyWcfI6sB81ajs6EBhyOjTu0mlcEE78gZHrK3JmUa4L8rQvONf9hRAW75ogVm5FmpAawRXtKTJEvZP9lQFl5cdprS6rXJ9gsZYbJGHT2la7CAtuAJVjtjQSKKvvoNOxc@jN@gLYCObU@sUlhW@1q6Th92v91YYMxbgeK8BkjOtJ73ARiYi/J9dWd8ExPSDK3NgKPmFwf1WtyujSYAC2jH19DwysTJgIaBwvMHNyeVfFKFNDs5oCQ1/Bp8vW73sgzsLmOvAeIFRTJj@/RuyIIPDQN5BUXNILbLFIesVUmest0e4Z/nr5wQLJ4AnqJc37fKEIjqPrOeBm8VDT3s@PwzTJn0rtz22tMxIEvCqKgvCtPgvjjjTh5EC4vxV8VwU7duImtAd0xM04sCBlzgABMW02CzNoFvLzNaHFoYSfypy@CX1FZDfkOFP992aLmzyaxKuyZEumc/OeLnxtum/Q4Aoy@dlkxbu3/O2DtYzDdGAd2t@hVd7EGds7cvQd6smaLOF0dEswgup7vOPVOX7f7b1DdSZYv/uHrNVeqr5D/QRkIhkwA3ubvc9/S1xx6Y/87OfieC9VJi/vjT@mK6qqw2zZoMPBEBo4ClmvhgFblq0J4U2p9r5MG5KsGnST/H6NF2CVG4b1u1@at9kmcUqAH1p9bB3en20vUWR4ozPk953G5eSBKseTA4aDn3clYKqLqOXt6/dquLWGYtlvaqi1uaMqrH19V7WP4f9bwkFWInWc828Fv2JF7VNn9lzx/QrCjABX3fZXrhhKkpxBxppKvdcAOj@cc0vn@g8YPd7jrjN6aEtiLIM1hxlSSQiYumVA/0NKi369tP736ag3aBPfqsRW445lATQ2@X3TpHQ4xP7KHGwo9P0aS5SnwlTYq0FqvZEAYvM13fH9RIXsahzaiwkMMA83J9dQK3sq@F1U43iOd19VOJwsQSf/pjWzV9VoYGFrOHWuQ6COgbcZB8pU22ncLd41pkrj65wbak7PVvs7RGLKr9VIyW/bTDtmuCGQ734Fcowb6zDhVSdgQyjf0f42UrJOY/3uICYxG8wjCZeA9K/iPabXi4Ngv4I9Aq0qjY0AriN9n@IJvzdTJ8CpFMzFFMFc4u973N6nSHuqKv@a1gF92pfQTAPjE3fpv9VKx3RzOemB5cZvVi6/owWcaSJwC6fE7zZsHVCa34kz8nbh7Suj1NYy3N6Sz1X57PTsG43ewL7LBpPBxFcBneUuxgm80wUJslQw8j3mj@bYtGSREhc2raXMjTfBwSv1oi2BMVI/YPBDYSKQ268Y9Fx/NDWcy7tACxW/e5KDDFmW3NumkmB@g69NU1UE46tApF7OAufbcqz1YbL5v94fMvy21wLESbq9R22sHUEOSgqvC2S3yNmQoA9wD2s6gcmPqepBmsB5PJzP5/VSVia0nwcKgDlQZCse9@esXX6DhlmNSWAlkb6/pw@/LI5Dx@wLnaZdxy768dHCSnaKCguN7KE3rKz3h9xj@tAdCLgP3Q/KMR1yE1BBBnNmLyi3AydK5GLRuak6rXATsiWIYaemJ9a@I8wycGt/yCl9WaBb0D/J3EvVrd0za4v2Bpfb/tvf9W2Ph4EAlZxIBgxfAwW9dNSJMFTnn6xy7dIzmsahxwTimA9xPQlLD@QytDGXTJBI4ugAk6BW8SZp75va/kNwU0dFuEWF1aioGnA337QazaKmrwqW1NgFr3M5lYJp5nSi0HOpbw6NIEwZFF4g@7LrxXwIIZhi6ipKnZ8u0X0Blzv6SBjpD7KqjsmuA1Ly3/7O2i2GRAlFCMNO8cRZZKtEGvs42aLleXUKVDtIVoKu2iAeZDJMlqc4koDMC1a8l@aHHNnGBkkMOJu4WIy1kZvLNOlAgXajsxPuNp1Ioucw0zhv34ce07@hJ4zw3/@Y8X6x@eb6IZBgDZefdkBOXlCutpNDkLxJddOuw4XLrha61RAvkrVQ2c5vHgyT5nI2ZSfEI4fInTAnm7Jk513BQQZdXRQD@gfceglqq9OkDz1TS68FmiYdQ48w0BkchCwfHuLcgBuMmOVwQf9CD1FWAjzNxkJwZzFExj3tSTrrLFZHtvcTmLzQm5LVtVk4GI6kSXUOn9Kg8zGkC30VXUzuf3qYPzKGw5WHh8UPofAC2KbqAP4jgz2nUM1/OQyehX75xYAJhMv14j6xNlagex9@qZfqheZN5qbVBDa@WLU8KKr6hNuoCBQCTYap3VCVidMO8EOXBOPbauMD0RvUBxvQ46EPOfoUTGoaNNSHtWKx2eoKuA6toJVGNMk67VWirT5EibZVHV0nrW03rNvYVnN@RwCQedAnp6BXHeJBcL7sUVekOi46DRUKQIUI@Jrg9d2@iu2mEniL4Z/wHphuV2MbilR1A7UfCOtqAdt0WzAWkXsr8fJPRLkG48i3KUeob1EOwNS3St8quJgplVuNwtuyt4q1Yd6ArCVky0@ysAATEvSgSCTc8riy5Ea1vXscxQB6f2j5AHDyRrUZ9EwypJ4sEEkSUTHL0LexU5A1bgM7N416JEhnZAMUab8PmqG3NFGxgEYNkl1Na2szoNCuA2BAcD3O@WkXhbBG@q2XByiOOZjA/M9W5kMCRzAb1B6vtAeB@d2/@reWJ9qDCeE/scMihP@lFf6JQQa99aaxaFyzBtnSLtVpA0Yrq@ITbrFVJxwwcECSFJj6ShPg4IwwBMEtYjf13eDx3LeBn9AIwEzUfKjsSHmC/uhB94pjhsHxfaDKYpDsjAkLaAfQlcTb4nmKnoGgn5l4LB5lGSAyMHMQBiQLYUCzEHq9xyBC1EzS0j/3ePr09JR2GTAVEtLxE4uRzCH3U8T185rQQ4ClLFPgnoY8kGWTA9LO7GyeQ87HejEr9kI366YfT2CUt9oFBgoPCQCIF6MVmx8uGIlUm1XQ6IqwMIlSXTomDtgXCtllFyz/UAdRABBZuNGB7bXsbrZccCN6S5qD283g6iBYE8GOXftE5/4n@sF8UB5tP0YaBObf7xEkBcJ/use5cS09mbdudZ7XTnFYG/pzU1FxE64I1NKeMBOOMGzcu9VTXDYqoBf7xS@AEnoC9CxekEaqZmRyhdJlrd584xZGIN2vwdy0@@zU9xAI@u8f1wH3K6l3mJotMs1KtuiwcpuqzWwWITZT2tdk7ivtNaXvlN6x9rvelk0S3hTEhr4XMZkPB4pk1ect9k0qswWYs9bj35Tq8X55uX88PXtQDt4U/8s@j9mD4BEKF4QeDOIv66b36JySs4t3g88pGEHHISTs2viDrz1SrPtN9PvOYuunHjYuY85@ITqMhc9g2jpjlKksU8F3dhKh7kHGKop4S1mEOfSCrnFIZZHUTYE89WY3Zpsa2q7L2wc0bCebNZNq1uyQeK5yCkwMdIm3oA2ioK05JHGzhFlEydxMPGAyg@sVZH61JHMJUBXr3Y2@RHbBON3x/lmnNIWJFLhx6EHFsXEAA0WGjk1DqJss9U649P2CXvvDfM03LGhosmR60ClrEcQ5GtTG48UKsKeygD5dp6lH24GMdvy8fMRVrD4FftVVjd7Mi/OCE2rA1IjOTwE5iIFAX04nACeSS0PAUUKgq2oAMgMf3Q4R91CKx65DcNKPQenBobDoSwMYaTxeP6ikH1h242TGeX0wn3WDHrZYdY7bNtuM@VWOcVsc4@65oKT0hYUHPZaPH5E7EO@ed2Zur@uNDBDvPNtVr//aTc9RFpxp99qNi9srhZBKrRXBbt9JpYJDg0J/JbDuocSmqZchCGOoR5xwGu2ZEj9Hgw7S5Nbz4FH8hql76cAZjmdzWqF9PjIvgAtJCNIkp0hCkozrQR505fcwaWhnjDWUPl5Wkkbfs8HgI4RJIV76EKf0OTA3cDLspcCIhCzHBC0MwPB3jBTNYQaEFFnXQ1IshfNxHaD2JpOOPBiSDgi8ILWmz36kN9pg0wMtrqZSx3Zr7KrDFA1icbpHYwDaPWrOsTiBv7bTCXANlRhA5WCmJ4FC@XwlKAr0Vw/IzAR6J81NQch0r995PMy/eUSBlHBgkXhhe7EAobuPLhTcX2QV7JlD5oRMK09eYNz/@QEHftEe@pfMHzFB5uSL51BOLxkwxrxnnsNhmvVFjny@Q@XIc6igOfLjjzgbfTkEa@cp6Aq6FgAUOJS9JyDPYB2lD5WTQ@7Uc9hPh49IDrj1@bxfIMNvDCb45ZB7YQ5/BGvCDzG61Ts9h4YXu0MoGGRfgD7sIYeMH2Tmi8dFuxbogY7FH0o@H9IQPHxCAn7DPDR9ZFx5aDJk/ntiG7nMYOKokV1bZd0Sb55YsxhoRx@vNXqMeCNa65lPDvD2kwt70vbZR3/4wwEbh5nep3jEo34KRz4eHdAHn13MkUt3fXnIz07c95wYDj4/1sf1@q33weM@yNVcbNQFtfnphD5iqAPmKPRLgmF@/vlnsD7p@7PgWfDRex9wP957FmeJxNGJP5488n/2s27/yQEtsyGW9XrCYS9DPzTphwTHHfmi4c/KiSRJmtHvw1cd4nM0YImlUUo@wMfD1t3uWMTd/Aldcz99@gh/5B8@61v8/Uhi7GgC8vbz0Ut7nhfUwdmHxT/kw7Bs@AFnbJH4x88foMqCj3yOjz@TeQztSiRdqvoZYenhAcvGaPVgRfcWAo1RAfxQB/xicbCCRPZgCX8sfvIHTwfUwW/Sad93fhbrUDD45ISog59Pf07/Iz7UAcwyDs7OHl9efIH74E@I/NEX8J3en54Gz84WZ4HHs3tnSv1EUwdfqIPFC3UQdoHYPBxRB@nFaYPQcp8/s6l6tsHLED4NPN5r9XIh0yz4w6eBg3Axk/OHm63sAQt3sc0tJkbwtlHI5GutG3/YynVeahdadYg3Hp/OPn/2BYGhn4Nnj/dAxw@@M1/aNE367ukoSH/982RdmHVonUAd5M8WLSZwCuSW7ZgGKSfwAHcPXijtF@rg/uDe8yn8KRySQ7MQO2bHFbW2@a/VIF5ahEaqHhqGhmwfmngRElqhZWi5@FyL16LMIjRRa2wfYgT4C00gKIXERWgQUkIKy@6ge/9/UlMrNRVQqZDNXIRMxBoS4Tqo1SqATITyR/AnhUJI5iI0g/@QTISO/ekpRHtDDw/UPe36WYBeHGTdwZA7GHe7pcdYXHv@8hKOP9@TMT6WerwXFpL56KL97qeH@1Qq5X48OWCMhwfGUmyucNR1giAvL09P@cxN5umJwSWPxemh77Mv8Bk@6TPfqX35dNA/Q7YGTz8@UG7PvNPp4Lczn82tEAlYcZ114vYNCcBn9k7e3cBivyB4PPexxy8vXq/3w4P7xG3VxOOhBbBcPS72YREW6bDLS0zaFIwHbAStjnjMe3YWj8F9POkNeEIk2cry4NI07cEVJFPkINmFTqczus4tCVAUhqQHF6c/Pbjuw4/pdCpGomOBVJxW9UAq4nV5vT@xp6d2GWEvRLvcC5equ@kvL9t/ni8vpx7y8eKf14uR9u@Z1wPJ3hjcLb54FqeeUw/GQRTm@vJyhkEC9wVC9x7vo/flxYqDX4/31MJ55gXe4TrAP@G/atCGRrsPXg7QlFDoaMzr6S0FbzTuSfpS9l/6I1TA44q4I1Avl5tz399/PoocJaL3nx6PHo88p0fBo4ezxx3l7HUf0CDLjuyl2QPkG3UQPGm42LDLjbJ4guvpqiwEZZjnR1Inu8LgfvIcvf4k2ZTvyPf5/iiVsso@OvrlI017AR0U5oLPAcgv7aFPz07XQrVB6T2D7xfaZjKEX76AnFlpYJl47IXzh4dFKETgT3rpwy8H3MsJQU@/uNwnO@JK0HvcJ2RHxfXFdcjp9@yj68V1@KX3ghbcEeslhkIsenJyFLXCieQJDNjskZ0SghQ7CAmCwfGk38IQjdLkBpZ7oVLpnjCQYLDTdnjki8ViTBh@Fz/EC@EFdYI7D9Y2hyvgsvoPnUwRhAe0YaQomCT0oOHndCIEk0BZ5nRaFcWPVjzMduieIIDBKcgyrtnhZABsYrk/hwnoR@oA9AyYwpAMn0mdE6aCMJ9O58L6k5OMY240grksfn7/27/8Z/D9O/j@mXX9s/8zFcPf3//2f/2Pv/vrv4HI/wLf/we@//n3v/03f2x9yf3fw/f/3Yr7e/u7BWd9KcD1P/3@t3/@t7//7b/8K/j@7/b3r15/f/cX/8n6/6/2Hwb/5nd/8ff4Y90Arr/809/9m38BJP4Fhv85hOHfjv4TO7gVawX/xAlCvn/3CvhPf//bf/23dvhfbINsxUPWP4H4v96K/xOKwrb8SMcSfn8wGIQfvPrJh1yDhz85IOz7I@wBVcFVwxRr7aFKmANCupDCXSMQgblCNu16@ATmVHs/Ei4YhUFdGgxhrjJX1wCGYYDuX48Fb0aGDnUBIjfBx5jweVcTzVWYxoaoIApoOJxKxpKpSDjpT6aS0Rgbj8X8bNjPJpKJVMgPhmqSjSdjKdafjKYi0Wg05afZcCyVgGmN0pdEhgFjh3W5aBKQFB4fIjjFpzHU4PCMOugLIswVP9ALT9/74aDvRNDTJO2KJB9CtIthYDY85PSjxf1j@osrHKHDdIxmaZffVaN5@qBIPnD3hHcweodyIbij4a4nc/wYwgsSngoQVCE44Qb4BDsmLBZPNaITnYtaW6hPVkrNirJ@4a5GPz25Xk4ohnlxvWMsWVNvD@2lv6At4KENaSVAk3pC/imMf7FP06QrnnAdH8HV9ckVgeDCQ4fcoNFc7geXy3ufevzkSsRcx2DCB9w/sp/AUE7BdDyRcIHGc4WB3zGXK06HEy7XHWgBYRBw059cJy/AXqfd1oynwWgIBmn4gjGN6VraosfjSnlooi5SDy5LmVqaye1xuxNht9vrPgEkH@ntenpPsHJQN6tqDoEuIAkITMHYf6IL5lRXPKkAjEx0IOU9ebFI@h@2aNLHx4bJ6TgJJ0Ue0654yoXRAHLqSZGyzmK9o2M/G/B/piw9GWepgxeqj27d0RR9kjpBixrG79Mzm7orepkY@C626D2hDt1IsTuyY9EckN9DmgbbNBBRo@rB4eEhmPM3Z66IqxZ8OmVsc/yMIXb4w9mJLx3N@YhlG3Ts/jNiEr/@RKOULuCeax9PtrAspGQM@TKgjQNAd@L7h3yCUG4akFInOIi6DjRLIpc4h6IfLFpPf3NATCi6/sXZU5sqZIHwuILNxh03ycMz94@09zdVSf6SjATOyHTaA81EQ0O9NFM/JX5K/lRp1Vq14ufQcfI4@fCwR8YPjF@8aoz9jXJ5cnCsuSNRdwTM/fSBVV824T04CyeCBrc8eLSdRTzRBMgPDfdkLA2zB2Jn9zPfuZlNyJwISkr@UX8wkMJ/VPn5l0OGcbtpmj2M/yZwav2fwk@uZhXhisdcXnSiMX56@gnniCnaFY6hAPsY2hrytsdnz@JIIX/CkUH@BGETYcCtc4fpgveIYZjbMCjDVCqejB9Qf2CYr61@Q@p6OUgUBN2YTvatB2V0qcLhWpmyXhOCQGW6EnS4OsdLOFqTRrWJC56oN7fjbFW6FUVOZdmNWxoMerhgLAxfeH4HObOHFlEleNDaM8neKX2EZ@KgZ4@X@kJ9AFxT3iTOMfBzQlEfcC8Ybz0OnJ/@0TC9uKcW8lIfPlhKAICDhvmEyDGTHRlgT6gXCtnD9fsGjUt1ZIvMcgficBdW1SynQXlJW5kMokStIYB48mC5WwQf0aJFBdTmiCYlEsqxclbxHyyw3lREUoqlcgHy0GlaJEu@dm6X3sMHqkn1Popeu3A6BFGIBcEJpwg4AgI6iPQQ3N4J@hzxHgLpo1lMF8nSMUDBgOgnlPhp0c54j7ePkB3Ri7ysGoDYKt1j1YA@erKLtetg00MqASzE2hF9jAFOH/B@u/XwMbr7RxiAHK8JD6bSp3TYu97nt3FBY1gHF5GM/KRvCQ55Ut1mM8HGPvqhaU@sLXrPGs6O2TDqhToy/ZMTq6m0E@rKw3u/4NLiyW8mP/7I/6TdTx5PvJO0iVefbwLDw9gjWSBHZnqSBvHQ7qXHE/Pe55Me0xPvlQfvYeRJhwBYtJhteO26Qc2VNNCC2w@G17@6VwK/UR79xXvFByRP/Ud36ZWfS4f8C/hKadYv@5/TrF0PKNNMr3zKCXcKX1zl3HGDgKHSx53sekZAlrFHTq/uucc08EOGjD5fESoDdBr3ss/36IXCZUh8m/FE/vFHziefLU7kQMCLUD9FPhXvTQg8@tJ4f@zhThefVvdTyH/sgWsaipG9QDzks3n9sqYd6DsBHlttuiHdonGB5C2AvEk6fXT36ejuKP3x4@p@EZg8@i32H4c20oDEL5D4DdUghkd3XvoVS8gMzOP6QTr@IXhkgAEm@XzAZL@2ldOi8OgOUjQY72yqX1BfkvNUnBV0lDDbJcJ6Ap48oEum@OTYF4McdWX20TcL8mYMXpJscMupTpPA2uXQtdMPcyYlwBEITLPPd8LEh8WnT5RTtL1fDyWjcukJNIdWMzneQ8f5IDkrzOB1Cc@t@rp@3aeGHZ27NmGbpbsCDeZyJL7VXYlqIh3O0Pl7BEE18CX0cmJpLMtLA5QN0R4AQ7QHwgVQiyCTbD1hQ6btRDQ57QaCXKgnRMvVHJ/vNlA/gXrb9HxQIRYZ0Jn3kCH5R2mim0CeJAjR0ikpDwLQVagPUAmkAesgPdJnoMjoH3@k7dvTNEwBEjgWIBjCjXwsAr2hFAr/DkoBB1I5AhlFfUgKAdo@YAo6F@0UFP3HFWQ76Hkgg2/kt/z0guFblx93qgzLLxX55rXIwLb48GEEFqJNEPwT8xjyQ9rLHw7s4f6YztUq9dZNoVHJNOGXDUeTmyOkjteHDb05tUTD00h6kkI8aXiuwQrdSx7sFzD2QKTUPh4l1qcvW2WYqlXzfnxqBliPfo4CGVCP15gEg5xFYARVfcDMpbHE7B4jiMc@EacdcmJhwDkDCskhg7O88ZbdOMsaOGOFwdx29d85hW4iGIZ9GEvAOYyOHLhH/IYn6P4KvdA@vIXshzpbOmQDEZdC/GRbGia1EjlhbGgh2MlPztkwreykf1B46EqfMzmUaCqVDIWO6ZAfA6wTCDuBiBOIOoGYE4g7gYQTSDqBlB1gHcyshZkNJyOR@CaY2ASTm2BqHYyGNsENhmh4E4xsgtFNMLYJbkqLrkuLJwle@sDhJum6go5pbDTppKEzvGKSyBigYV9HRoHQ8BtIyB59EwnlJXcjE6mQXVCJqSFQOBzf3IP2cWDTHosqv0WH3yrZurMjYayirMkNEdiCroNWKizwSCgQOu8xjd6MFAVql@ZlgQNjQDDBSkkXQf4F77HlFa8vj9eDlIAY0uz6HrILMCOFPCw53cwSnz3J4X3JFrbwXmzWUwf0mjFb7pw2kRaVx7uOmgRjdCduG@tHVLDI0XcgwhYEtsGGSnmrzBt9urfIyNeL3EG4t8g3RFl4Y/tyIW88BHnayUrGf4It7ZRn2SkCaW0wA@yjLIkMvGpQfDwi/YU9dv3@t3/1f9C//@2f/w39u7/@m//vP/8vGP5P@PN/gc1Ch9cAf/bn@PPv8Od/w5@/xp@/2MpE4CPHrt/91b@H2//5P9C/@2d/biX96791@aNrRJCCUZucf/nP8edf4M//7fLH1oB/@acWIGZx@V@oHdPKA1B/9l9oGkpDLGtkf/V3NO3ygYHhsSXv3urjj17vKwRrNtyT0OPrdOuXH@rI9pDX5wK89h27ufNhA3i3kOscns246XtgzlheRKileY4foseuHaUaaP/waMKoRnAA8jbvg9FjLw64ofb/I31Mu30IA9HkqZC0pcPt@tv1dm1SEdbnYoA6PEHJRoVh75oSmN5SIN9kJrA0gjhtITNS1pIRm79VPPvVGUBcjmRJpof1UnZZTm6Y9ND2EXrwv5nqotDiMGQ9VUGOsqRs51N2q8AddfOq2aCU1zEwZdz4fm9nJRHCRIMmgWxrfiNj8YZwwf8a3abl7G5TqBVfdRj89MDEHG9rpHVBadrl@gYsctqG96LFFdmFt@i1Ae5Dx5FHatsLfR@w6/b21kVtxYVQhvS@h2DYqpSlMtZJ7G5SeCspvJUENFs4ia6JhcOvaCADB@pF72u/@10VtZttI1zYc5x2QDJgLmitA/pFeWoM029RE428q@zeIt9CyT6m7X7yoBCdc0a7vG8yAM7dPOnXbbkfdegNzNuG2p8Tub0Ts9Na72PaybPVKQj3qNdcWrccm9rXcrsFfgU1@@j7zoLCoX9kQYHvLCge@3ZBr5sV8@6gf5@/31Y7jppYa/gNMqvjH@wMUDg0/hWI3kYdIcU6CXq8MOXJ2FOe3lylPXuOX4R4xnlsdufMRX3rYVqcxFRVU7CWBz5rKkw5VLSCtw5Y3nfQuX2e8UBRdcHYfhxEslxrFTc@asSrAwVGNT8@vivZp3/iHpr1YOjuuLIe2WwrNGed2YyoLUah5fn0JCmS@fQExqcsejcMxNsgj/6ObgoPe4bQVn7P2rStaR4Vjx0wvd/GSexdK9uNxI89Nc1OdEMhGRomdLwgw@SLHnL8GI8tJyzBKpKHM9Ai7ZkeLzJxqE7UgaCo@JgV5n6FvrTBjQRxmkZo8dOcn@a3KLIn0R7ez3ntrFe/Oit9FfZw3nX@8C6CHWb4af01j5Gz@p7int4tzsrmlNf89fQ2t@ltfp1eUdIN8zXNJBJXe/D664qOeDYYAHBDRuTbZPjtpx/fkLNDyjoajzW1Mnw3iX3B4GH4Q0ozAJqxwYMiyId/fWfA3Zrw9nv8/3oDOtkL39t8xJhtLkHfTApo@5EpmkEeDVd4wQPgJS/qnrfFrUU7/51l2RMdMsPz0y6iuBR0m4WOqWmCYqz3Vx3E35B53Nx/I/dkxz9tJe6hSZ/56XH4/SbKP/UFmVsKfY8N6d/C69S4IXB9oq@@r@Ko6IjSU62zbD0hP7tjipHHGwjQ8Tsiw/lnXu/7YmWBSGvpIZtxhMLS@/wjC3evVTMugqatPRBVBw16QB4rJg9za0ttaT0SJVvn3dt61Bp/rJas4pNi32QI8ME6zZz1b4r1fk19NjzrKn3HiLCGDe5WGZ96cDDicwdv2/DXsejbNSWrDOtMaaeVd6yT91pc@lqLb0mFI5OWVfJ9IvktoftumdsSNQvZRoXlft0Q8gZzjpNlnvdsY7RivtpiqvJGJ2ActpiqvDOqPO1RqOucRNOZeGxi2rIvvJQEwRJcZ3BtwxURwhz0yRIop25o1zpLXiRlwmlbVosdc8@jLbrFRe/2PuIWFOWEcSH3ZV0m/26Z/Jsy@Z0y1z1gt8gtIIrfKdJuBWyerzWBLIjmO9oZk3DmDpevqW34KCqn497rF7fkPpb8tHvmPgaF7BbcxwUPKGV3332cJwHDfdwkgbH7@AoCm77l/sV97HQLBNDhlgQ@Y7ytwvGedx/nPN4XirzlxCk36D5etynAfLJuCUderOXVnr3rr65XVQXBbxmVfholxoCLitW6f/STbwj@Cah9VgckfkzT4SMCjBOQnUFja8SwyoFhI0heo@DZN3wcO0tT9vrGZg0F0n3prUUVlJIp0UfuA/euMrIIw1Sy@AhXIBD15vF@imj2zczsW@TYpYOEkkbeLZ9wL0jsgb6HpN8D8PYijrzJ77TXLgqrAb@PTsz8Hp1vyHGKIxShM4B3D1nI1J/dX6kUtvUuLXbrb7fQ2zUCbMSAA2K1EkG7pdPBhkPblBSmqdqukJBU3O2TtvPgx@6UKL2vshGtYPfMd5JJtF0zVAzbnd/7teps5UPSdlQQJt6HHq1eth4XiC7GpI2u27JUrc4HJGzpnD55ZlRAsc3bQQJnqRs/GSveG4acvFaRRHPtqknIHETf/SlnWqVv9mXQo//XTV@dnGCCA42IYCvnuhRLv6q/wn5XLfvdMagdJrwqYJ9hvX8ofWtef3WUfUW5vCn2bQNiop/Oe/caR@sSNiyH2cGWZf41WXtj4uM52paRbxW6xv7K2nfYtp4TfINvr@cWFi60EvTZbuQYF2bH4fcZ9dYikWdBx2gJYkk2Hqvia0o3Vfs6rVbF9zUxpuAYDZdf3cD6bgNvNx7iIxXQX7Hc6uX4qg@yT7Hu27imvrVzYe06qOgltj6RZSsS1D3xX1u7aEFE7amRr1XLXRh0E4mE9@1WBPZayLsZx6mvbhOspy1hPz4zT94Whr4TQ1U3Pz4orrcuZSQCjAGO7NtY4mf3ca@ty7b0@au@C/ks2C2O2rjGm27A7WglNHU4HLIlm68mMEQwPUecjcQxb4HffjJbw10jlA7c0Hl6IsPX0xM65zw92aMYNs16G@kPB/a7AsJbr/w62PVmeudVirgAMJ1YL5yyF@DsR04tP5QDfLnb@kWM61xTxZQcZwdcH8ItqrVnhCfCeq13wjkx1qvbQFI94ShOYcMxfBTKyoXQuPBJXCvtcj5ahg4eZ2ZoqmK/221svf@PHK5mOEuvhOypMueIG4hVCnmCa4siyyHL2Rcjr2siZ@5Z78biFGsJ2eGNnxYGQbLjE07BlGMsadaRKmvXD8NLMhGCiY8W8LgnCxN8ZRLI7p7V5IoErTIsSoMBCBJjn19oObjc4FuUAqoYyG1ebtkmL76yD5myfcLIKWz2OjCw07PzrLdBh@NgTaX8wNnNFxiLbjI0Ps8dIk5aBAq@CbgkrGDSv5X3o2fp3b2yzseL@D56nrBlf7FGCmgdGURe2eIz@fyyvTRtb1oSPbC1c@kcW0DZx0ykyT5lEH3UNI/rwOUc5oBBy22Ck3nnKWgPPn9/TH1QiOJBDzCat3xrwMBV0Ggj22vetUuqQv9AR8LkrSpQHrFSSbGAw9rZ28EOaZAVibW8@2wF4/qh7/oBNxOpDweoCy1Zw/yOKGOYHDe1kWX6o43O2lDBrmx1AecmtnUTganGhz0Ff/S4fIDF5/K6djABvL378cHSvG@zglL0/oG56cc7RTWTydxMWL1xnhlkhplGF@6zobKvM4oWGKZwIfcz@VJvea4mbmZiOHTTvc72Ir56or/QpItJ7kIrUFK0O/HdRRapi@gqlovkMnzoVjwvi9FE7la8NYSMLKSY2Wh83RcaWo/VDemqWqk2Vkyxdd0eXI/Eu05nlFCalNa4yw6uF8J1sqPM2q1UybgW2rmqOa6OzCm7rCU68dZcMbLtm@zwclmajxeluNqVYrlrIdEWtYs5v4xp/EWLupvdDOPNi@U4xU76y0zO6HcTPh/TzWUHyQu@fydeNnNX/YEe68XGzRQXmU0uRW05vLpQnsujXHPG@7RRsRSfUUq9NJsL0c64J18od412u5fP1udj1rjT@qNopzI1e0k9HolMM8JwFI2VpqaeLGczVwkznym1i/Jt27xbtpN1yrwwbxKtSz4l@2Y1k49M8y3GCLUXl9JVcx6/CN@oF8qlXBrVx@fT87qsTcf5qFS7mUT1wW2xp4bDF9fN2UW3TOnRy0432RiFk3l@wTNXMVWdRG5S1bJeWUyzzzWhk@ObWaEXD2VjtwV2VKkt@dqs3Gh06lqnNUkYV6x8VwyNqNot38xkx8XyJMneVJel5HmpOc3lSotZLywO1My034lUbuPzclUoda6ZyAU3NSs@KVeTmdHlpbFst65Kt1XjDrp15VKKistFtp3Vxed8zqg0ykxVHw@b0ZHS19oJKafyl/VS1CyNMxfzzl2qlB0LYr03Vsc3HbkzNaX8iClSy9z4utUT5kVpNecK0XL7mhkVGryZyAwiTWYkir2xXDNWg/PyatCc9gb9VO08lBeer/rZdqxR0NhK0YhWlSXVvcmK0qpxLbLjeuqidNcrZKSKEsvVBa1@fjFbhMNdSazPYyt2cTsqRqUFHw2Va9nbiu/6MtzwlX3ZbF2N1AZUOF887wxiVz61KKyYssg9J3I@fTqNLvJTfO9WuaXI@iQmh5LFG98wYeidVKUy7xml20auw8ur5F1lPI7fNajbWclQ9XDysphJMfVxSD/nRtXSXUJSitF59lwupEqdVStpFspTOXlRHuQvG3r@ZsLfpgqD5nI5HiQvhXp5nKGEZL7RGPUG7d6i2zTqy1Alyo96vsJ5ofo8gH7cbhbDl61sfDBtRNpXeWVWvyn6Vuptp6zlqmO2UE9O4zeJyISaLS6TmaapSFr@vJKKX0@lciGTH7RyrCoIt8/8FTvmmjfLUNJI6NfF22vN8Jk3PTXaG2Yjy@tKl2nfGUbsQqLuFp14KTPW@av@wrw0EjdKWK1dh9hrsdqSY7OO9Nytq6PMhLlq3a6Y3nxVXNRN3myO1Vg/ERufL4xnfXWlX1HJ7oiTW9WcWh7x8auutEowMVa56ebECt@9DIcyrcFFRShezAarljAJjy6epxc8xxv1TLd3LsdnC80nRpKzMnVT7dwOEs/PoZ5Q7aakzLjVqJfM8A3HTLvNcuy53DWMIt8qSdmopEzz2e75eJK7W3I3xmI1vYn3ZHFZ18OhArWodittfqQOjKJxx49Wt8U7pTINx29rIzFh9sfsRGLLbTGUqGoNX95Xl897g2W8PRVmPFiG2nVJY7OZ0ahG1dhJYpZdpgxTOTeuqr3cZUbKZMrJ8LUWTlyMc@cXi77UbrWrF31Ojd71cpF4rTcIhfvZamFQj04GiXo1ES3nqJve8rrB9vNJiR1ycm50uYxqqXI4G2fa88bF9ehmqFTlXKazELMR/kadJzqcqLSEVTzBVEK@0TB1qWRC0Xqcapl5s1UuziM@5apUCdeXS/62x00jnPjcNXx8dzVc1doCp8rD8nODvWlPyzlpNGrHs/xNqJZthqYrY85p5TqVytcVNl9ezIrzYbMTMrT8hZbsLar9XL0u9LR@RBN7tcxCDM06nbvr61ZNmdxeTy4aiV5t1edGsbYpNuK1hUk9g8nTnpVbxd4iLxriqDF7Vs4X09s2E22dT8qt/sw3St11ZxHpthYqV7NtkZuWrgcJs1VdaJVLWZSZSbg2YKh5q75amUJGLVTnle5CbK9WGSlrPLOLK4Yrn5fyt6YvVShm8rWbJqfLtdp5OZ/hJvPKvHyb8AmrZqUfk8bPd1RdUeSwfteUE9lQxAi3YvlVjh@dh6bn2cnN5U2K1djWRbtSuWKHMj/hE91aPt6p8J1M5vJqeSly7Xpdq1@1bqiaT7m9u7thajdyOSWWS40bNVaa6ZVOJ8HN1cw1FypFJ715eZGdV6bTziR16euaAhdRV4LANuZymREuQHaSlDCd1XPVurEMP69Gz4NZXr1tpzLaeTyTW4r9mTBbhTL5mY8xiot5Py5pyfBNd3EudvnKYHDVyA4j2ky7iedi1GVKrCjtXm5YSS2Fq4tyuzg1hWa/F5V8Rkgb3VxnWkaLX0rnfHw4axldGTqfqMVusrmUId/lk1e65Asl@SzFdypcnSkPY7fVy746zy0q7WUephxJVqyHYupSaU@TY@XiyshedZ6vkslBq3cxhoKnw7shL7V82X5PuBblKnV3e9UeF@rTNjO6vq0k6q0LX3IV0c@feXV4zqWWN6taKCSIqcGsNF1EtDKfPE9e1Xj5clFttERhEG@Gr@VzZUXllcQwlBHZ@WyuML5lLJssDMRsq6ro@RZ/kRDUOscwi86dWevcJq/C56HrUHMyD4WNypwJiV1FWnar3W64T2VnxpXWabKzgu/CzHSbowZ/LjPVTqO0UpflQthoZao58Wo6X2rlpaRH7vjyeU6u8xILZkksPrjRW@NVdtajOuKinMsmE3fhC5Agw5BT826UE3hDGyxGTLkyvZAXo@m4rfsmC6bhu@suYqlhe2gwfLl8Uy3NC3pMvTRGChWP8@GLjq4ljMbzZFnKmflhuyVHc6n2oFe76DKVG/EqdZ1r3iWEWJ0pPQupTjMe4suxDs@wDXUyM2FE4gdjqrwM9XVeFnQuMa09xwrTqa@/nE1Nn3aXOL9KdgbjHDvjOV8k01OfuUX7Ug5J1YQwMGqd@ey22AELUWnPWgpVvGtpkSvpQmxetGuVMVvPNFYmk011@NvooKuzoiLOGhEzdlkSBglezBfuxqP8Rem5FOqKz6E5K@vX15HiBUslRF/WVPsy077WrpVVmBMy3VqyMu@vcpNhVRQuSuG83m3E@80rTi7AMCo9l0Nau3hevuv35CEjqkqt2QiFqLt4uNC5bTyzs/51fXWjLi70wWWmLkduxZKi1m/bbP5aZ6qJbPE6N2rc5ZbJeF2Xe8LNIHmjTHznEZXnMko5TiWEmZBtd5iWIEXYxGLV48YCw951xuPkBbOKGysmoxjzUXKwSvXOJ2znrqqe3yzHzPlkcVfP3rJTwceydV6jrs1VPXZ@3vFdLc9bpYHcKok8w02WI@MiOxUu573reMaX1EI3vkK/PVyU6wOtU2ASvV6SbUYinaj53K8vjesq1c6XLyKJ/NJciIXxtLpIXmiZeHO5aF1Ho@O70aKWbMYbsQU7U8eFrFYcxBj11kgoi5uLQTErFMSKaFRWPX5CxVfTaqmYLPhiAtetd@9CYoF5bvZlczgQb65uI804w8cuavX53V0@w0wS4qhQks9hTJxzlcWyOeqOe9c1IyJRaq3rK8VX8VXz7rraV@qdy8qwNx8kEnX9oj1KTVddrSE1fNqqVeqp5/n6RM6vbkHg4o1UbNSSC62OdJtvhGqUGe9k5mCDs9mytBwwpVjoSlRCl4vJeep20omPu@N2btboLsajeDMRU6fCKmF2nmNToZXoXk6aDN/rzoe@8DmlNlfL28J1VC9X51rZrKvCVSgZLt@NW5PCtOWb5K6KPTPXCWm9cKc8n/pyMbAKkpV2KlztXY2ypfH5tXFxHU5RN0VpOU2OzuPnvjoMJtORUUu25bA8YzqM3J7PhPEkxFXzXFtf9FrFcr/aDycZzScl5uZV/PmyW7/jTC2qMJSxjPfnnO@iABZEXurGmr62qYUmMBcJ3c4iV8ogEjaU22aTN3NqYtyKpIRoUW8ranuhjtph6fo8MZ7z0tWIygqrflRuNTr96mI176fG0T7XnLUyxVulE8kp2nBh6Gw8dRVuc8/1iR6pmVq93OKzyvWE48S5byFn8xW9OaP6g2qm3yk@T8VZO1rLRDPL234oOr2bjVhldVvohkf1XmYozhud6Koxj2T756zSmEjaRA8zoZu2UhgnF60L4Yq6XBWE5TB5na23o62rUWockQfjZj20HNckkb@7M6ZsqTsoX7P9UqydvU6NL0QjIyRaKfFyxCyqvdpdPNcXoiHKNyxNmHCuzEcuC7c@85KXY8/Siq2aq5SoLKstqdcczDJauT9qTavZCybLhmfni9okctFgIlMuO0nmr/SuLlNCIZZZtGqVuDG8y5jtqFoPz5LaXV0a3Ib79SHHT0LxJOjgSr93t2xlGtl5uVu9aBoZZbASfPr8SjkvFYtZhboQO9Vn45lTxWkm2qqVu9fP1xl9cBPrmUaJXTwLzHKp1C5zPL/sZkrGuNq@bCqlRGjSz1YS18N@WWmpdSlyRfGpxPg2wShN/nIaEqL1TLT43D7nn0uzeEMdKyZ/U7hjzWoDlF0p1qpp3flklRuGxEUkWrg1aoO@dge9dbSiwtOLRrffEEfKYt64NNtXkUmTHbfn8jiucJovWkjVahw7iOAkLHarKhNVvhqYt83q7EpnmOEqPhW0c@FKosphbZApNeKXYe78vJtPtdjJc1kIJyvRaWYerjUqPiUmaPnSYCKHcuPGSLiWYMrQiddHl6FmVWoN7qa529SySa26PTGlXHbm6lVuPM@PZ6Ob1iIC06ubdtkwmo1bs1@ahXuXCblXG/Zv8sXcNZ/jOCNRU3KF2libtnuT@UU0Ro2KkdtRJXEpDeLjRElYdq@mWqp@uSrlhhdRX1e5TJpdzpSfa/Loudozzd5zQmo3ry@ZTjbBK6HnZcK8HXYYg7pITgrnUSGxKg3ZREuZzKbTfq2hqKVl/boCbE6EIzfnPSajda7rZrt/IfC3Fy2w9C9VodS8vdSa57cX/WlfoeQIiG@O0a/Oy0bxNj@@Y@elxrInsb5x7WpeiyViYqrnm8Um1eE0H4t1EpPL6qyY1/T4ogJaf1Bf1stCo1qh2EmlWxj7LkWWTeqVVXsWbWSE23ivMhfn0Vg@s1CGyWQrtLi@POevkz2tNJ@0LtnBNTO/S42NCdfiGhleFWtU9lmLLPMLsxCKFa7iF7fXwig@7xem4VJm3uyU4maqKnY60ed5Yz4WqkVWvFnM5uF6sXZtKtHYon19N76CVohR/GBxXUgIlajQD0mru5xeVHtKi8uEmEsmPG@1r33qQHmuCr5xPVyMaPFCaFHnYGZ8l51e9uO91kjunGcvUkOqH@ULvhsjXrqLP98@VyT9duRLTEDlJMXG7LoCJknPbN1EF9diqsuu2rlkh@sVV2zhislELy6mqVI4fFlOlbuU0YxNQFqe5@Hby7wcvq63b6JTX76aX/SHzbtWIzevJO@67KTeac4ucTIWYUJzsTZqtJbV4qIlCfHCuFEQs5SvdD03ailNbOTbBZ2p98VidDS@OC@eC9MrfrooKL7QoNRazp6nEyF5WZE5QVeKDXOY4SPd5Diy4Eta5vmqTS0vuMIlm0u2k/pY4i9H1ZYxMmYdTZQy0efYwmc2RnXpKpZv3Nwqo9awWtX5XCWcMIT8uDmJ37VGi95MKPQvKdFMzXh5cV6Nm0p2WZRuW5Xry34ztOTryctqUV@EekzxuRmamUwr2azfDHpVXSqPYOD0dVuqmpRBpZhD9ZritGEpNG9nrvrJgZE7DyXLl4taS6r6QteFxigfNma6jxlOauH8Si1cRsR5YtC4vpqE9NysP/Rd1RPM3SirzqtUzOxHOpwxTjVEttttM1qhsTKMSrLV811dy4zQCN8lshcr9qYX0frTYTfZnZzPnrvdynOv3byA5rz1CfFm5ZkaXF9dGAkxxbP9VjZXzqgzLXSpTxpidFJWu61wV/R1F/nS/Dl8FSqOSj22Wh2uVln@Uu8oyfykV8lxy1Er2aYihVqofxcRtMtW/rlbHE5HfK684CO36oXhu41WF9NzPZmIs9HUjDMi7cmk7UtmZMmXiAyXw3C2MIvnmb7e6FCFmi/XUVXoBY27OFdljGi/KptGK3HTLKQauWLuonxVuBXLqWaJu731da9LuULmJn55NRxHr7qskWWyleGoGaZG5dy4z5hmcio1paJRONfzi@Hd@Hoy7c0Ts7LRXSlX3FQaTFiR08adspKIZ67bz7FaKFKoMIW7layEE7FFiurzYv@SkRvj205SKlwwXXkIE@g8yP/4tjLVeVE3hqkO1LyyUhK5Vm3Q1i/kYR0olHtTjRcnKWk8FCJ3VINpJouJjnwl8rVuY5Lo9qTbm8tIQpwuYP7aza@uxDwDrd7qNofT0G28AKZrNPpc6gwn17Nq22jE8u2bcj1KtZ8beZEtFcrl9p3ZZ6u10KA4M1uJ5EWB5SfZcbWwzPaypXmRb3UufCNf@KbPz4rtjFxo9zljsbwLpUJ6RhxR8VG8khXzrDmPtUU9mrsc1iKcXFIXtcukNmnUL8PZy8K1qI71UPY643zi7WVqIsWWAzGTOW@XurkBlbnO5UfhtmjwDcU3LxGwbFHm/vCrjwoRdF0hYNRMlfrWm@PtYy5OvnLwBDl5Ah9v3zl3Ap19tg8SEO3nq4EWKMfvauETwsf2S@pxTzKIpx7j1uLJ673FAOscJ0AueI4HfUROOhZ3NkJdOmZek/FRUr5GANnxJDsouA9GHk/@wTiGL9Dgd1ACm8gTdR7CG@83aSMcwXM@WDyP6vFka8vTw25TgwRCk3GKCPz0u37AUxV@hIxkC7hQK3r3beuHTnbyA3GGppCTRlyBoItktU/FQEy7KKzWxPj12QwUOZDF2Vj7ynscOIZNhuIpcr4HrfhN/@Q@9eg/4tMuWjAlTpkYU33eHw/U4UykZVob9Rb8cvVM07EoHYGywj/SPiyTjacZcjpfAn6TdCpkn8hEPp/IOaN4LBU5OA2Pi3XTdGB9qtNH2ksCfvw5dp28kVL6aOJIoXXIx@Q@/phW0qGTyb3yeKL4fF7TlzZ9rM@DET@y3hNtansi3puP5Kl95oiuOI/W4ynH6PurinRdVfih6jZo8kqy7WdOyOFbTgeacNp2f5oJvKnq2zEiyhM32emIb6Nwl5h7lVNSHThzqQm4dbc@lUDGdzXiz4dpPHryNh1r@OEDHqFxYvtObFfgC6VNe7LEH1MfCD9xCxwfpz8@tg@F4fFQM9xAwzjJirRooSXDg8knTiqvaks7s2SBPDl1Od1CeebBvVWv/3sgHageyOQTvpNCBzALxGLvDjgNqMnWqNeiCsNlQVnvg@I5Pt4TPOWE/uikOSf@IDzKDTl358mkJXJKD1xOaRuUnIFBe@0TJ0jsvYQPvRFXgjO3lfRhNJ1oZP85aNFrcwTfYvWkcZK@zhk0pvhSaw/NIjMkh2hsAQy84BFoM84UtpvGaQt0fCMPX2F9EF@dnJoOBPOcri9RN@LDB4ivr5I8H6zXpHloU7UcKy0y7LykGl67qYFxeHamW3Mf08QP7gSiyJboyVbqCFKxru8kTyB5wpnDd5KHiHtqvJesQzK@PO2dZAmSrWci96erkG7t9L8DYKKXJ4jrk6k@mZwke6wDPfAokBdLYXton89h7FoEaKthrPbYzU/bR6PQH63WsYRtR7ygfxKxsgBQpD1258H7jbSQVDxa1GPJxVaZFk/oL/Q3C7OdI4HFT6QkULtYvvdoBz@9RQD0P1Cl9Nt0p3CrtdcV3ZGfIAw7A2xtYFaE/uWXr1FmC@Ku/LGPjvRZLYR@uFs1tLi1wWO9XWrTrlamlZ1pfx776Jht7eb4SGzq4XTK8EaFWH1r069FSelDGYD443Y0ujx56U@bmHvjkT5ea48NH61u8W0@ht9ID3pEkR7pp3ubIP/9XOVQ7iEnByNyb6Ms8Jww7uQNO401dGAX@gyg19x8JWf8jszYvfTXVvb7anMA9JFOTXhzYilaHkzDM5vAPeRxVrtu6wQL2aH72IrHl2ZJu8ikd5BZ5@k9AQLzFGjAkc1R486YKClB65lU0POhcNRPXMwtkJcNmxxl9T18@ifoXMg4e8ie4ntEdlUSvYc1b8DX9UZ@nb3ucq@qZ2n6/ZW7tx5qdn9yI430W3kiUvcJRsljOkSvD246oV@@rYf@YZz5smm@HXvH8LyvK5xGdyTxe0Tw5R1Gf1PIdqsQfqR3OD4lrwfWvjkkkUMI9w9KG9f6JyfGcbu0@va7FhhSdbKbjjRbCJ0EMJS3c/ltm@tsozrt0xefTMe48W@sMPJGaiIVYLKfUNvqHKdzRTJ4b8euj44iHNlOwSfZ0cLUHcok0bFtwQx28gX5J2xmi8nIT@jTA1XtexyDyTYYCAbnhA4A8lvHWa3NKsu83BQPxdlGLz2wT/lwxt0TiPloR5FxBSLQ@LRlE4k4GpBuc4LdZsu@kQzydjmSjqMRFOU8fYDOipb2oY9fxyP02gT6sDeTo/HxTDJycqWt58lIvKMeXDlOQcdQbA5ran3qwvh1QyDMGUy0N@dbkjZ42bPKYJ3haZ9u@WV76iKdSEG0ideN7nhBek/W1JyeurCYtcC//OHgIzM1dKYnKYygzGh8CzR1QAuK9VKVY3zxbSCJjsL43lpbmxC/bOKECGICLYWlBRVh7rHfbYuniLq8lHUmHXFaZCk8t5f4jcvCrA9Wv3Vii6YaC/K7hMlCKDjVTJWk2AWRs@voX6RfNuephshTRPaMwSbnlODZwHjw@QIrdmn5SgZYy0Bi8VBi7xaKe8xJFK7rweXC9kNCbX/S@0fKCAocP0QiUPZ@saZT0FxEkl8ow2l6PGsNWYEPr0BQtk6Z0IjvKBZBrBNjSe6h@njPYsCKIS6uKPf2PIUiDsGYIquqhkKOrqCY/xQYYDH@Q/MmX2g0gvZR@pbHOnq5W37M@IggObDOfi@17caL3up4XKDVKB@wsojbKi@9QU70L@ERFmuzCbvCHNlp8QrPI7RqEGDJ3ZtqrOG9FjhhCXncyb4zkJch@1QPDewo5N0mm2crW8DJ5gBvseLDN7nB8TweBFERJipQnBNkGYi2ePFhww4MIkec8n3r8o17LPNxTbyVHniTHthJD1rpFlEbqCA/1DdAx9tAroMvG7gX2rUB878pK01DpUtVcrpUUNW36D75GqwRhEmatAE@WzelJZXrhNOdhMBWyk97Wt9K@biTZy3g6/R7K92W77Dd8msqd2A/75aPV8puIIGcwWA/svhKSoOKJFvvSt@kEA1L47FKVnZsbyJ2Vqe0F0RsdRIANYHvj8Zue5beYPGxjsYhfcZ1dvrZFbSXpD55XpNhvQLmTcfa00e2uETK9BHGLchIAuWQ5I9bKAhOFDTa6blnTualnXm5hRahPjrFUs5JobsdHKr2uoun0a37F/xxOvsucQ7cwf7EDxblC6vy1pMWuwwiSvejaz@bdrWJqU8FK9Ku1FdGkU3Zy9cY9yuJqoozUH5IXhPulClYz4OI6lTpf1zriW1F4WiKN3xfp9ic3gCwjvi@14SY@EL9/w)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)

### Explanation

MarioLANG is a 2D language that looks somewhat like a level from a Mario game. This answer relies on some implementation quirks of the ruby interpreter so I could not use the TIO interpreter. Besides at the very start the MarioLANG program is simple. This is what it looks like with irrelevent characters stripped out:

```
#
#
 >


  ==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
    ============================================================
```

The code starts with Mario on the top hash. Because there is a hash under him and the starting movement direction is right ward he then moves right starting a fall. This fall leads to the `>` which pushes Mario one square right before he continues falling. This fall lands Mario on top of the leftmost `=`. Since Mario is travelling rightward he eventually falls onto the long platform with `+` on it. These `+` increment a tape cell (The memory model is like brainfuck) until the cell reaches 49, the ASCII code for '1'. This is then printed twice by the `.`s. then another 7 is added to reach '8'. After this is printed Mario falls through the middle of the program until the program ends when he reaches the last line.

#### Del|m|t, etc

The lines containing the Objeck block comment and the Del|m|t code were switched in order to fit in MarioLANG. `#cxx` was appended to the front of the Del|m|t to appease Labyrinth and Incident.

#### Cubix

Cubix needed to be moved because of the new mass of characters at the start of the program. A slash was added below the INTERCAL to redirect the IP. The Cubix is now in the Incident/Whirl/Cow once again. A padding x had to be added to the Cubix capsule to avoid a division by zero in Cubically.

Comment: @WheatWizard It doesn't work in Ruby 1.9.3 and Paintfuck. These errors are inherited from the previous answer.

Comment: @stasoid I think I fixed them, I can't check Ruby 1.9.3 myself, was it the stray ␉ in the code?

Comment: yes ___________

Answer (score 6):

## 120. [TRANSCRIPT](http://web.archive.org/web/20071018030927/http://www.corknut.org/code/transcript/), 4382 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOxxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#B bxe xxxx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoO\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPV
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"24 5 10 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","y c #FFFF00 ","t c #FF8000","z c #FF00BC","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","g c green","r c red","zxxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","OxxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __","tyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy   ","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOO"};
//}"                       _             _              _             _
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015"" 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002535 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4490 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB/2CRWlvkuIFBO@URK3Fq0SJN5EiKeqytUEQIEGCAASA17V1oufFdvc4Zjztno5229PH3WFHdMTMkycmwhPuiImwX/0V5wfm/MGZzALAi0SttXZ3UyJRqMqqysrKysqsShR6nDH8wx8O8EPXVXk5kFWTNgXDpPu6NBP0IJ1d0p85yYiFIxSFUBl9MJ0IimkcUwc0S0sKL/XhljbVsaBIK0GH6DCt6epA5ya0OeRMWjB4ThMMWp2a2tSkVXF/rghdmKgjKYAZJ5IyAChT0DVdMElylG4pMjfp9blXCbHd2jQdkg06L8i/TH4xaV6dTDilbwBgnM7XsoVy5lX@BF1RdUPAUnjBMFSMS9L/9T8sCgL/CjRFVzhdUsuZ6vlOikWauq72pzxibg4FSMfGipIsGBQPeJ3Rmk3gIAboA1oXuL4FRomqTmMWejKWaYnmNY3uydwwyNOyBLDFUJIWkDj0CtIPaEOdCNsIGLQiCH3a0AReEiWe1EoLC1NQDElVjCAt8WN6Lsky3RdkyLBBhfdDYfTU2IqyKg5SfZWi4cNrrxBf3x0KAKMITuMFDWiDjVeRlEAJhwZzndM0QBII2ATETWkCzCCZboMWOENCZoMshqD0Cd20NRuqNKdst5KeSRzNAb5TnZRtCLoJzQuScumhoAtQJLfmBs9cl0wgAZI1Q9cFTqdvdEHw7jLlTpVQmYo1mNiQIOm201N3oVZ0Q/dZOYKcZlIHeuTm@pLi6GCaPnw6gW/a5TqhCtU8/eXwAcMWG0IXa7qH89Lp39AG8/AgwHfB9piB/kJBqRRQRaYZVTMZLqABggETEGQ4DGIoMAsHNXmrYvr0VV9sMZUF1YfeoEsK3faTlvFTXcdxtiEqN4ZGy6oyAHpCY/WpgvRQ6HgIuoBXYaT4aWEGVFMVq4/UOaHwzVCCTjOwS7geEIjjkfaWrCAEBWkBvGdT1KnXUOUpgYOchokMCFSBrFhiSaTbtMhJMmaBdCzKwloXjKlsYp6p0seeB3Eg9IO0gwav9hFoos6gOg4KJREwhiZbI48gBcDQESppKib97l/92/5gAOVkeF7V@za7tum@yhOpxhFkQV7QyLCqwskELYDzY@1WdqhgxslSnzOxemVpV0GQILXO1ancp1WoUJ9LMLSG3AyGoygKvClYTG6JQj894caWvJAszoWGT7gedCypgNRNmh2gP@egl3iBOiA8E5hMTTFJB7QC7TaYnzyfjj2fPj4IgJw36D06ZJjBCTBc8IhEwZ37a5zTzmw6FOoyTM5QpT6lLc2hqoTpAE@7@LSqCYrHvVOG2@/We25vEOWYx3sipfmgKCl9jxt4PAv1ur0nfJq/l44fT17l3q4RSpljKThaBQ/vdVEgcciYmDETTlKC2pJuB@zQVppqPCHFMTm4FY10eR03syIOyGSAbKkif4AYChqyIGieUJD1opRAuL3NxoR9DX1Vht3gY@nR5z5w@7abTkqAlu40FMfqjaSi1JK14RRkNBBFMTSQ3jqyLs8B8xgoxE2YjP10j7A1kfwgWIhInAtuXaB7IEcdNiIj0hpxmD@ActIuYTOCHLjdAS30t8YzyAIY0qbxRijL6hwqJrjhtAUSRMHKuQF0EWS2GpSxGmTVSGJ2mzZWQK5gaT2BTgZ6EowFHHUg2m3W32ojgEfCFgyUZo2VLRE04ZZQCm9NiZtxQ0siDKkJSAl9SfMCih6QQYI1r2AlUzIMDVBEUCUJBcKx2O5QezPSTJ3JBO5AVq@Yrw4obPz2mEJ5Q4vCnJY5ZTDlBqgLKZCF43lBM215BS0xTJBIr6cdEhmw59CgMaQOP7@um8wl9uy6VQfKeqv37BmRQyFjK0QBGWQqzdnaHN2XdJBO8vJ17QAwe1W562cE2UHgZ9c7KDiKADCZsBD4qQnCDRh5PpT4IfAuYqdY4tGai15XD1HbtYOAD4jrqhEZ9uzHMBVk1lGIxrtFBLBH35YDcywWdbYTQTp/O@LrJXPGZE/B6hpFmA@2YoMMFwTes4kG2lMTNTeYbBxViYystTq3picQGIY6DFNglqFpasYxyHbJHE57QehW5kZflsyagj3LmPpSMlUr3JPVHshSAwYT49TA8NOetHjVIhK3JvjIoGagNIkGnYbZ9nkKLOJxiwZIORKfQ@CtJBeRtqQI69cFgAQoCJTyiAaRn0WQAM2lwntcQcL3QRghLj/twlHm8kIAc63pklMnKDLoDpnMUTvL6iBmRBAttqAmcprbOz2tBTbRxdzu4EiVFM8X98ePH93H7jMQxx8/foLQKYY@YcgHoU8kFCAhhAtiiOTwkxCm3pMcGPfofrl3Sl54H7HbFjiVrCTNw90fH0ce/dw9a1/DePWCXAIxBNABvEA5bm86jUGv13U2h4YGe6LV@oZF2T7hhoagDChhoam6SVdr@cJTPXNzkXYxU0NnZKnHKDAZPk1guIHB4dqTHywHJzsEG6pqpkmHYTyBLgKQbTVRpjqFAQrGgjSRzBIxUWQFWXvTaU5qDuq1CihtGySirk7W4sWgBH6o0q7DiAsV6R0zD@dcOzWKqVPbytuKT2D8BI20IE8NeJ4OqNbtOtIGTCIg2m1BsKCogc@HkMSOW0fakClSJBpzQb1nob/HOLSB4wjcV3uCvIhHA4IsBs3FKogjMR6lrAsd6L8HsScvtVjty0CZMKwCC/FVAucYmDcgy8ugutNlySB29DbFqTXvPVAua2xEdqW0a5MS3qhU@/VA13YphE@gr8YqSqJN6AmUnthOEWC@vs0pSsaQ/OyAvsHobQrJbUx6IvnZA3Bs6xagqKChiyS5RDMJ1RtVBaN4TsAmqqJaqACpJIVjGuQShClpHz67kn8HmZ4gTsF0YnqSguFvgAVSSQIp9nrSe6BAF0Tdue4B06e9fWQD5hq@UQ7oHcKbU92Uhb59/e9/3IcOeNs9Q24JKj8/XgeegG7YVQHx3d6ys@IN@dnfswRmNJUljpCBhL5VJM@hWcbJ68D@olHa0YHAkNOhc5dO5wJz4g/MXF/hMwtzXZCnfcG57q@EkHhXBbFyK9KEtAiuqE@RKeqd7K8UKCs/mrW6rHJ9Uoq13CAJm962@kVYcANoHLMlkUBYfQeejp5Db9YXQEcwp9YvLil8q18lDb9fG682ZCjG9VgBjDGuJ71DRUQi/h5fW8MF5/SAKHNjK/iEwf1NtRqjS4MB6DL29T0w0DLBENA4XmDm5PKuiFGmhmZ1BYa@Up4uW7/vgTgLm@vAe4DQTJn8/Bq2I4zAw9hAVHFJL7BFIukVUWWut0S9Z/jr@QcrJJMniJc07/OFIjiPrm3AzeKhpr2fH6dpkj@V2p/bWmckBfCqKArCt8YszDvShJMD4f5W8F0R7OiJm9Ae0BE340CDlDkDGMS0ySzMoFvIz9eYFqcSfipz@ib0FZbdoOOY@u9Zi5s8msSrsmRzpnPznix8rbpvisEVZPKzyYp3b@nbB20Zp@nAOrR/QKu8iRbbO3z0HeLJMpbQHN1ijKD6Hu14dY7fd0fvUJ0J1u/@KWu1F6vvED8BmXAGWGBvs/f5b7ErLv2Rn/1UHO/FyuTlvfHHdEVVdbCWDTocDKGCo5D1apiwZdkyCG9Ktfd52pBk1aCb5PdrtACt3DCs3/3cvE02iVMC/NAaY@vw/mx7kSLTG50hv@90LicPVDmeHDAc/LzLAVNdRClvX79Xwq0lFMt@U0Kt1R1VYe3ru6J9DP/fYg6yEqmjzb8V/IoWtU@c2bbi@w0EiwBX3fY3rhhKkpxBxjKl3usAnR/OuaVz/QfMHu9R15k9tCVRlkGbwwypJARM3VKg/yG1Rb9eW//7ZNSbYhPfasRW545lASQ2@X3TpXQ4xP7KHGwo9P0SS5SnwlTYK0FqvZEAbPM12fH9SIXsZhzaiwkMEA83J9dQK9sU/C6scT7Hu68KHE6WYJB/U5vZK2o00LA1NJ3rEKhj4G3GgTLVdjp3i3aNqdL4OuWGmjOy1f4OkpjyayVS8ts6044abgjku1@AHOPGOhi86gR0COU7@t8ulKzTWL87BZOYTckjCZeA9K@We0yvFwdBfwV9BHpVGhsBXEf6PsETfs9SJ8CpFNhiimAu8fc9au8TpD1VlX9N74A87UuopoHyibv03@qlY7q5nPRAc@M3K5ff0QOOmQjUQpP43Y6tQ5Hmd5YZebvw9pVZamsZbm/N56p8dnr2jU5v4Nhlg8lg4quAznIX4wTeGYKksFQw8j3qj@botGSREhc2raXMjTfBwSvxoi2BMFI/YPBDYSKQ268o9Fx/NDWcy7tACxW/e5KDDFmW3NunkmB@g65NU1UE46tApF3OAufeekoTbiAUv8k7myUE3MDjdWknuHcxwVp8Jp4F680nw2@7RECcpNsb4Mbay@SgpPC6QLainN0O@gA3yKYTsKxMVQ/SBM7j4Xw@r5eyMqFyPlAAzIEi@/y4@We5EBg0mEwmgZVE@v6ePvyyOA4dsy90mnYdu@jHR6tUsg1VWGhkg75hZb0/5B7Th@5AwH3oflCO6ZCbgAoy6Ep7QbkdOFEiFwvPTdNphZuQ/UYMOy09sTY1wYRBv4Ehp/RlgW7B4CeGnapbW3PW/u8NruX9t7/r2@4UAwEaOZEMmBsHCroAqRNhqM4/WfXatWc0jUN3DCxjPsTFKqw9kMvQxlwygd2JFwVYWK3iTdLelLWdk@CmjhywhYXVqSh30FXAtDrNwqavChYr2RWvczmNAht2OlHoudQ3h0YQ7BGFF8im73qnAEIIppi6iqzop0t0X8C1lD4iRgabrKpjsqWBmPy3v7O2oiFRQhbCsFM98UTZqpFGAUL2f3lenQLWTiErQVdtEA8SGSzxKU5TMBAEK95L80OO7JEDJwacHWKsxtolzmWadKBAu9GTCreyTiTRc5hpnLfvQ4/p39ATRvjvf8x4v9h0c/0QSLCGy087ICcvyFfbySFI3qS6adfhwmU3C312iIvKmqlszzoPhkl3OTu@E@LuQ/hOmJMdX7Ktr@AMhn40igHjA269pGhr0KQPPVNLaAaaJh1DdzMQSByELAch4jmBu5eY5XBB/0IPkVcCPM3GQnBnEUTGDfNJOuushEe2NyuYvNCbkqW7WTgYjqRJcw6f0jChYEgX@ir6r9z/9DB/ZAyHKg8Pix9C4QWQTdUB/EcGR06hmv9yGDwL/fKLAdaJy/XiPrF2bWB4H36pl@qF5k3mptUEMr5YrTwoqvqE24gIZAJNBrtxqMrEIwjooUuC8W2x8YHIDeqDDejx0IccfQr6Og0S6sNasNhkdQVch1bQSiOSZJ32KtEWH6JE26KOrpPetjvWbWyLOb/DAEg8GJNTkKsO8sA4X/aIK9IcF52GBgWgQQR8jfD6bl/DdlMJvEXwT3gPRLebsQ1FmrqB2g@EbbWAbbwtGAvJvY14@SfCXIN55NuYI9S3MAdg6lu1b1VczJTKrUbhbd1b1dowb0DWHLLlhFlYwMwMclAkHG65c1l8o9quQ45gALk/tBwMOHkj2gx6JhlSTxYIJ4komGUY2zgoyAK6gYObRjkSpDOyAYK03wfJ0FuaKFhAogbJlqm1bxpQaNcBECC4nuf8tItCWCP91oUEBMcc9Gv@ZyvzIYEjJRvUHpe3B4H53b/6t5ab24MJ4T@xwyKE/6UV/olBAr111bFwXJMGydIu1WkDZiur4RNusdUmnDBwQpIUsKulCVBwRgiC4Baym/ZuyvHct4Ge0AlATJR8KOxIfYL@6EHfjWOGwfl9oMpikGy7CQvoB5CVxJXjeYpuhyCfmXgsHmUZQDIwcwoMSFaBAc0q0Os9BhaiZpKW/rnH06enp7TLADtLSMdPLEIyh9xPEdfPa0QPAZayVIF7GvJAlk0OSDuzs3kOOR/rxaw4Ct2sm348gVne6heYKDwkACBejFZserhgJlJtUkGnK8LCJEJ16ag4oF8oZAtfsJxPnYICUJBVNnrHvebdzX4O7nJvcXNwuxtcHQRrItixax/r3P9EP5gPyqPtJEkDw/z7PYykQPhP93hOrrkn89Znz/Pa4w5bQ39uKiru8BUBW9oTZsIRho17t0aKyy4K8MVx8QsUCSMBRhYvSCNVMzK5QumyVm@@8TkjkO7XYG7afXbqewgE/feP64D7Fdc7RM0WmWYlW3RIuY3VxlRGiI29/BrNfbW9xvSd2jvWZtrbuknCm4rY0PcWTIztQJEsKb0tfZPKbAHmrMX@N7V6vF9e7h9Pzx6UgzfV/7LPHfcgeITMBaEHgzjjuuk9MqfkbBHe4EMQRtDxNgm7Ns7ma3cX634T/b4n2vqRio0/mrMZid5o4TOwiWeMMpVlKvjONiW0PchYVRFXLAsxB1@QNQ6qLKK6qZCn3mz1bGND2215@/SH7cGzJlLNsg6JWyyngGGgS7wFbRABbdmQxIcTrIiSuTE8wJhBg5bYV0tiS4CoWG@d9CWyxcbpjmvROqUpTKTAjYMPCo6NdxkIMvSaGkLbZKl3wqXvF/Ta2eZrjmdBQ5Ml04MeX4sg2mjQGo8XG8CeygI6jJ2mHm3vNNpxIvMRP7T6FOhVVzV6YxfnBSfUANOIzk@hcGADgb6cTgBOJJeGgLOEQFfVAGQGOrodJO6hFo/dhuCkH4Pag0Nh0ZcGMNN4vH4QST@w7MaDjfP6wJ51gxy2SHWOe0LbhPlVXndbFOPuuaCk9IWFB92hjx@ROhDvnndmbq/rDQ8Q1z/bD7D/2gfQERacaY/ajf/cK4GQSq0Fwe7YSaWCQ4NCZyjQ7qHGpqmXIQhzqEeccBrtmRInSoMO0uTW8@BR/Iape@nAGc5nc1qhfT5iF8CFJARpklMkIUnGxSYPPifgYdLQzxhrKH28rCSNvmeDwUcIk0q89CGa9DlQN9AY9lKgREKWY1IsTMDwd4wYzcECQoys6yGplkJ7XAeovclkIA@GZAACLUir6bMf6Y002IxAi6qp1LHdG7viMEUDW5zukRhQ7B4x52icQF/bowWohkIMoHJg6UkgUD5fCYoC49UDPDOB0UlzU2Ay3et3nj3zb55/IDUcWChe2C4ygOjucxEF9xdZBX3mkDkhZuXJC8z7Pz/gxC/aU/@S@SMmyJx88RzK6SUDypj3zHM4TLO@yJHPd6gceQ4VVEd@/BGt0ZdD0Haegq6gawFAgUPZewL8DNpR@lA5OeROPYf9dPiI5IBbn8/7BTL8xmCCXw65F@bwR9Am/BCjW6PTc2h4cTiEgkH2BfDDEXLI@IFnvnhctGuB7u1Y/aHk8yEOwcMnROA3zEPTR@aVhyZD7N8TW8llBhNHjOzqKuueePM4nEVAO/p4LdFjxNXRWix9coC3H4vYk7ZPP/rDHw7YOFh6n@IRj/opHPl4dEAffHYxRy7d9eUhPztx33NiOPj8WB/X67feB4/7IFdzsVEXtOanE/qIoQ6Yo9AvCYb5@eefQfuk78@CZ8FH733A/XjvWZwlEkcn/njyyP/Zz7r9Jwe0zIZY1usJh70M/dCkHxIcd@SLhj8rJ5IkaUa/D191iA/pgCaWRi75AB8PW3e7YxF38yf0@/306SP8kX/4rG/x9yOJsaMJyNvPRy/teV5QB2cfFt/7eYJvzQq2GZYNP6DFFol//PwBmiz4yOf4@DOxY2hXIulS1c8ITA8PWDZGqwdZurcQaIwK4Ic64BeLgxUksgdL@GPxkz94OqAOfpNO@77zs1iHgsEnJ0Qd/Hz6c/of8aEOwMo4ODt7fHnxBe6DP2Hhj76A7/T@9DR4drY4Czye3VMHX6iDxQt1EHYBszwcUQfpxWmDYHCfP7NxebZN4DKETwOP91q9XMg0C/7waeAgXMzk/OFmK3vAwl1sc4uJEbxtFDL5WuvGH7ZynZfahVYd4o3Hp7PPn31BIOPn4NkjoLL4wXfmS5umSd89HQXpr3@erAuzDq0TqIP82aLFBE4B3bId0yD1BB7g7sELtf1CHdwf3Hs@hT@FQ3JoFmLH7Lii1jb/tRrES4vQSNVDw9CQ7UPHLkJCK7QMLRehiVpj@xAU4C80gaAUEhehQUgJKSy7U45ae4jW4rXPryLX/5OaWqmpUKAKmc1FyMSyQyJcB7VaBYoUofoR/EmhEGK5CM3gPyQTTmN/egp5Qw8P1D3t@lmAkRtk3cGQOxh3u6XHWFx7/vISjj/fk3k9lnq8FxaS@eii/e6nh/tUKuV@PDlgjIcHxhJmrnDUdYIgLy9PT/nMTebpicFljsXpoe@zL/AZPukz36l9@XTQP0OiBk8/PlBuz7zT6eC3M5/NrRAJWHGddeL2DQnAZ/ZO3t3AYj8beDz3sccvL16v98OD@8RttcTjoQXQVj0u9mERFumwy0vU2BTMAWwENY14zHt2Fo/BfTzpDXhCJNnK8uDSNO3BFSRmcZBsa6fTGV3nlgQoCtPQg4vTnx5c9@HHdDoVI9GxQCpOq3ogFfG6vN6f2NNTu46wF6Jd7oVL1d30l5ftP8@Xl1MP@Xjxz@vFSPv3zOuBZG8M7hZfPItTz6kH4yAKc315OcMggfsCoXuP99H78mLFwa/He2qVeeYF2qHt/0/4rxq0odHug5cDVB8UOhrzenpLwRuNe5K@lP2X/ggN8Lgi7gi0y@Xm3Pf3n48iR4no/afHo8cjz@lR8Ojh7HFHOHvdBzTwssN7afYA6UYdBE8aLjbsciMvnuAauioLQRls@0jqZJcZ3E@eo9efJJvyHfk@3x@lUlbdR0e/fKRpLxQHlbngcwD8S3vo07PTNVNtivSewfcLbRMZwi9fgM@sNNBGPPZi@cPDIhQi8Ce99OGXA@7lhBRPv7jcJzvsSor3uE/ILorri@uQ0@/ZR9eL6/BL7wW1tiPWS5SDWPTk5ChqhRPJE5ik2SM7JQQpXmu9MgYpgsHxZOCeHCA3uYHkXmhUuicMJJjgtB0a@WKxGBOG38UP8UJ4QZ3gboO1teEKuKzxQydTpLwD2jBSFBgGPej4OZ0IgeEny5xOq6L40YoHC4fuCQIomYIs4zodGgCgB8v9ORidH6kDkDOg/hoCfCZ1TpgKwnw6nQvrT04yjrkR7RmBAYuf3//2L/8ZfP8Ovn9mXf/s/0zF8Pf3v/1f/@Pv/vpvIPK/wPf/ge9//v1v/80fW19y//fw/X@34v7e/m7BWV8Kyvqffv/bP//b3//2X/4VfP93@/tXr7@/@4v/ZP3/V/sPg3/zu7/4e/yxbqCsv/zT3/2bfwEo/gWG/zmE4d@O/hM7uBVrBf/ECUK@f/cK@E9//9t//bd2@F9sg2zFQ9Y/gfi/3or/E6qrTmmew84QaI62JBYH5h4@rB@kT6mzZuEGom9qdDK5vl/gfSRM7ustvC9V6SW5vcVrvd6mkEk@0rGE3x8MBuEHr37yIdfg4U8OCPv@xH1AVXAJMsVaG7IS5oCQLqRwCwp4a66QHcAePis61d6PhAtGYVCXBkMwfObqGsAwDJhU1pPMmymnQ10AL0/wgSt8MtdE3Rds4hAVRM4Ph1PJWDIVCSf9yVQyGmPjsZifDfvZRDKRCvlB602y8WQsxfqT0VQkGo2m/DQbjqUSYCMpfUlkGNChWJeLJgFJ4fFxh1N8bkQNDs@og74gguH5gV54@t4PB30ngp4maVck@RCiXQwDpvWQ048W94/pLzAp0zHc0WBpl99Vo3n6oEg@cLd07kD0wK1p3SZBUYC7lXUXCmVzcPeEd5AQymEaDXc9mePHEF6Q8FSAoApBdFJQTA7uBnA30GFoQ1iHMFAbi0Ut2lKhnYtaW6hPiBwq11acrWPXajX6CZPM5Z4P7kxBI975OEmDgRMDCpH1cb2cUAzz4vq6Zrj37nWitRDhob30F9SSPLQhrQTgSU/IPwXNIPZpmnTFE67jI7i6PrkiEFx46JAbZL3L/eByee9Tj59ciZjrGAyagPtH9hOYDSnXsSuRcMFc4AoDw8SAG8IJl@sOxKMwCLjpT66TF2APh@/WjEODNhUM0vAFywLTtbSFjseV8tBEjqYeXNYsY4lst8ftToTdbq/7BAr5SG@TxHuCbYOmWS1z8HMBRoBfCpSiE10wp7riSQVgyqYDKe/Ji4XS/7CFkz4@NkxOxxUJUuUx7YqnXBgNIKcpq66zWO/o2M8G/J8pawKJs9TBC9VHB/poij5JnaChAYrN6ZmN3RW9TAx8F1v4nlCHbsTYHdlR9Q7I7yFNg8oeiKhR9eDw8BBsm5szV8RVCz6dMraVcsYQ8@Th7MSXjuZ8ROEPOkbQGbEUXn@iUUoXcAO6j2eIWKpjMoZ0GdDGARR34vuHfIJQbxoKpU5Qu3AdaNZoWKJBST9YuJ7@5oDolnT9i7PBOFXIaulxBbuNO26Sx5TuH2nvb6qS/CUZCZyRtQUPdBMNHfXSTP2U@Cn5U6VVa9WKn0PHyePkw8Pb0UAdGL941Rj7G@Xy5OBYc0ei7ghYQekDq71swntwFk4EDW558Gh7zniiCeAfGu6JjhFmD8TO7me@czObEFMRakr@UX8wkMJ/VPn5l0OGcbtpmj2M/yZwav2fwk@uZlXhisdcXvQoMn56@gkN5hTtCseQgX0MbakC24qLZ3GkkD/hyCB/grCJMODWucN0wXvEMEw7DMI8lYon4wfUHxjma1sBkLpeGxMFQTemk32LYxldqnC4cKisF8ggUJmuBB2uzkEejtSnUezj6i/K/e04eyrYiiLn3@zGLQ0G3X0wlqIwJJHTkWgRRYIH1WCTbCTTR3j6ELo5eakv1Acoa8qbxFMIfk4o6gNujOOtx4Hz0z8aphc3GENe6sMHSwgAcNAwn7BwzGRHBtgT6oVC8nD9vkHjuiXZL7R8ozjcklY1yz1TXtJWJoPIUGsKI25NWO8Wwke0aGEBrTmiSY0Ec2ycVf0HC6w3FRGVYqlcgDx0mhbJ@red26X38NF10ryPoteunA5BFJaC4IRSBBwBoTiI9JCyvRN0wOI9BNJHs5guknV0gIIJ3U8w8dOinfEebx8hOxYv8rJqQMFW7R6rBfTRk12t3QYbH9IIICG2jshjDHD6gPfbvYcPLN4/wvzjuJB4MJU@pcPetdODXRZ0hnVEFMnIT/oW45AzAWwyk9LYRz907Ynlr@BZw9kxG0K9UEemf3JidZV2Ql15eO8XXGc9@c3kxx/5n7T7yeOJd5I28erzTWB6GHskC@TITE/SwB7avfR4Yt77fNJjeuK98uA9zDzpEACLFrENr902aLmSBlxwL8bw@lf3SuA3yqO/eK/4AOWp/@guvfJz6ZB/AV8pzfpl/3OatdsBdZrplU854U7hi0u@Oz4hMFX6uJNdNxHIMvbI6dU995gGesiQ0ecrQmMAT@Ne9vkevVC5DIlvM57IP/7I@eSzxYkcCHgR6qfIp@K9CYFHXxrvjz3c6eLT6n4K@Y89cE1DNbIXkId8Nq1f1rgDfidAY6tPN6hbOC4QvQWgN0mnj@4@Hd0dpT9@XN0vApNHv0X@49CGGxD5BSK/wRrY8OjOS78iCTFNPa4fpOMfgkcGKFuSzwdE9mtbOS0Mj@4gRYP5zsb6BeUlObnG2U5ADrP9Q6yzBsij0MTAIAfsGORQMbOPjmqQN2PwkmSDWx6GmgTaOodOtH4wJpUARyAwzT5JCxMfFp8@UU7VtvMC1IzCpYcWDWj95CAVHQ1lciqb5Rb7Lfm6Tww7MnetgjdLdwUa1P1IfGu4EtFEBpyh8/cIgmLgS@jlxJJYlssKCBsiPQCGSA@EC6AUQSLZcsKGTNuJqHHaHQS5UE6IllM/PklvoHwC8bYZ@SBCLDRgMO9BQ/KP0kQ2AT9JEKKlU1IfBGCoUB@gEYgDtkF6pM9AkNE//kjbt6dpMGESOBcgGMKNfCwCvcEUKv8OTKEMxHIEPIrykFQCuH3AFPS02qko@o@ryPZW9EAG38hvOS0Gw7cuP27bGZaTLtLNa6GBffHhwwg0RBsh@CfqMeSHtJc/HNjT/TGdq1XAGi40Kpkm/LLhaHJzWNfx@linN@fDaHjuS09SiFsRzzVYoXvJg/4Cyh6wlNrHQ9v69GWrDKZmNe/H55OA9AeWyQ4T6vG6JMEgpz4YQVUfMHNpLDG7BzbiAVvEg4mcDRlwTttCdMjkLG9chzeewwZa3DCZ2w9V7Jz3NxEMwz72JuAc@0eONiRO1BP0BYZRaB@TQzaHnf0tspuKa0R@skcPRrlEznIbWgXs5CcnmphWdjI@KDzeps@ZHHI0lQL79ZgO@THAOoGwE4g4gagTiDmBuBNIOIGkE0jZAdYpmbVKZsPJSCS@CSY2weQmmFoHo6FNcFNCNLwJRjbB6CYY2wQ3tUXXtcWTpFz6wKEmGbqCjmlsNOmk4eMCikkiY1AM@zoyCoiG30BC9uibSKgvuRuZSIXsikpMDYHC4fjmHqSPA5v2WFj5LTz8Vs3WnR0JcxVlGTeEYQu6DlKpsMDDt4DpvMc0unZSFIhdmpcFDpQBwQQtJV0E/he8x9YjAvryeD1JCVhCml3fQ3YBLFLIw5Jz5Cz22ZMc3pdslRbeW5r1XAa9JsyWb6uNpIXl8a7XKikxuhO3XepHFLBI0XcgwhYE9sEGS3mrzht9urfKyNer3Clwb5VvkLLKje3LhbTxkMLTTlYy/5PS0k59lp4ikN4GNcA@NJTwwKsOxWdF0l/YY9fvf/tX/wf9@9/@@d/Qv/vrv/n//vP/guH/hD//F@gsdHgN8Gd/jj//Dn/@N/z5a/z5i61MBD5y7PrdX/17uP2f/wP9u3/251bSv/5blz@6LghSMGqT8y//Of78C/z5v13@2BrwL//UAsQsLv8LtaNaeQDqz/4LTUNtWMq6sL/6O5p2@UDB8Nicd2@N8Uev91UBazLck9Dj63Trlx/qSPaQ1@eCcu07dnPnww7wbhWuc3gK5mbsgTpjuVShlOY5fojuy3aUaqD@w6MKoxrBAfDbvA9Kj7044IbW/4/0Me32IQxEk0dk0pYMt9tvt9u1SUVYn4sB7PCsKrsoDHvXmIB5SwF/E0tgaQTRbCEWKWvxiE3fKp6y60wgLoezJNPDeim7Lic3GD20fVgh/G9MXWRanIasR0zIoaGU7YnLblW4I25edRvU8joGTMaNI/x2VhIhTDToEsi2pjcSFm8IFfyvi9v0nD1sCrXiqwGDnx6omONtibSuKE27XN@ARUrb8F7UuCK78Ba@NsB96DjySG275O8Ddt3e3rqorbgQ8pDe95ASthpliYx1ErubFN5KCm8lAc5WmUTWxMLhVziQiQPlovf1Qwi7Imo324a5cOQ4/YBogC1orQP6RXlqDNNviyYSeVfYvS18q0j2MW2PkweFyJwz2uV9kwHK3M2Tft2X@4sOvYF521H7cyK1d2J2euv9knbybA0KQj3qNZXWPcem9vXcboVfKZp99H1nReHQP7KiwHdWFI99u6LX3Yp5d4p/n77fFjuOmFhL@E1h1sA/2JmgcGr8K2C9jThCjHUS9HjB5MnYJk9vrtKePQddQjzjPKC8c7qlvvXYMhoxVdUUrOWBz5oKJoeKWvDWUdb7jpS3T44eKKouGNvPxkiWn7HixueueHWgwKzmxwelJfucVdwDtB6d3Z1X1jObrYXmrNOxsWiLUKh5Pj1JimQ@PYHyKYveDQHxNsij86ebwmO1IbSV37NWbWuaR8UDHkzvt8sk@q6V7Ubix56aZie6oZIMDQYdL8hgfNFDjh/jAfGEJNhE8qQKaqQ90@NFIg7ViToQFBWfOcPcr4ovbcpGhDhNI7j4ac5P81sY2Ua0h/dzXjvr1a/OSl@FPZx3nT@8W8AOMfy0/prGSFl9T3VP71ZnZXPqa/56fJvb@Da/jq8o6Yb5GmcSias9eP11VUc8mxIAcING5Nto@O1HQd@gs4PKOhoPkLUyfDeKfcHgYfpDTDMAmrHBgyLwh399Z8DdGvH2e/T/egc62Qvf231EmW0uQd5MCqj7ERPNIA/PK7zgAfCSF2XP2@rWrJ3/zrpsQ4dYeH7aRQSXgj7EMDA1TVCM9f6qU/A3eB6dE97wPfFYSFuJe3DSZ356HH6/i/JPfUHmlkLfY0P6t8p1WtwQuD6RV9/XcBR0ROip1qnBnpCf3VHFyLMeBOj4HZbh/DOv9322skCkNfeQzTiCYel9@pGFu9eiGRdB09YeiKqDBD0gz1iTJ9u1pba0ng@TrTcL2HLUmn@snqziY3PfJAjQwTo3nvVvqvV@TXw2POsmfceMsIYN7jYZHwFxSsSHMN724a8j0bdbSlYZ1pnSTi/vaCfv9bj0tR7f4gqHJy2t5PtY8ltM9908t8VqVmEbEZb7dVPIm5JznCzzvGe7RCvmqz2mKm9kAsZhj6nKO7PK0x6Bus5JJJ2JB1SmLf3CS0kQLMF1Btc2XLFAsEGfLIZy2oZ6rbPkRVImnLaltdgx9zzqoltU9G7vI25BUU4YF3Jf1nXy79bJv6mT36lzPQJ2q9wCovidKu1ewO75WhfIgmi@I50xCS13uHxNbMNHUTkd916/uCX3seSn3TP3MQhkt@A@LnhAKLv77uM8CRju4yYJjN3HVxDYjC33L@5jZ1gggA63JPAZ420Rjve8@zjn8b5Q5H0yTr1B9/G6TwHmk3VLKPJiLa/27F1/db2qKgh@S6n008gxBlxUbNb9o598Q/BPQO2DSyDxY5oOHxFgNEB2Jo2tGcOqB6aNIHlhhWff9HHsLE3Z6xubNRRI96W3FlWQS6ZEHrkP3LvCyEIMU8niI1wBQZSbx/sxotk3ltm30LFrBw4lnbxbP6FekOgDfQ9Jvwfg7UUceZPf6a/dIqwO/D48MfN7eL5Bx6mOYITOAN49aCFRf3Z/pVHY17u42L2/3UNv1wiwEwMOiNVLpNgtmQ46HOqmpDJN1XaZhKTibp@0nQc/9qBE7n2VjUgFe2S@k0yi7ZahYNge/N6vNWcrH6K2I4Iw8T70aI2y9bxAZDEmbWTdlqZqDT5AYUvm9MkDtAKybd4OEjhL3PjJXPHeNOTktaokkmtXTELmID7UMOVMq/bNvgw@6vDrzFcnJ6jggCMWsJVzXYslX9Vfob@rlv7uKNQOEV5VsE@x3j@VvlWvvzrLvsJc3lT7tgMx0U/nvXuVo3UNG5KDdbClmX@N196o@HhiuaXkW5WuS3@l7TtkW9sE36Dba9vCKgu1BH22GznGhdlx@H1CvdVI5FnQUVqCWJNdjtXwNaabpn0dV6vh@7oYU3COhsuv7mB9t4O3Ow/LIw3QX5HcGuX4UhWyT7Ee27imvrVzYe06qOgltj6eZisSxD3xX1u7aEFE7amRr1XLXZh0E4mE9@1WBI5ayLuZx6mvbhOszZawHw8QIO9lQ9@JoaqbHx8U11uXMhIBygBH9m0s9rPHuNeWZVvy/NXYhXwW7BZF7bLGm2HA7UglVHU4nLIlm64mEEQwPUecXYij3gK9/cRaw10j5A7c0Hl6ItPX0xM65zw92bMYds16G@kPB/ZbGcJbL1c72PVmeuellbgAMJ1Yr/ayF@Ds528tP5QDfI3e@pWX61xTxZQcZwdcH8ItqrVnhCfCeq237zkx1kvygFM94SiasOEYPiNm5UJoXPgkrpV2PR8tRQfPdjM0VbHfoje23rRITpoznKVXgvZUmXPEDcSqhTzatoWR5ZDl7IuRF2OR0w2tt5BxirWE7NDGTwuDINnxCafA5BhLmnW@zNr1w/CSTARh4qMFNO7JwgRfTgW8u2c1uSJBrwyL0mAAjMTYJ0VaDi43@L6qgCoGcpvXiLbJK8bsE7dsnzByJJ29Dgzk9Ow8@G7Q4ThoUyk/UHbzBcKimwyND7eHiJMWgYJvAi4JK5j0b@X96Fl6d6@s8/FieR89T9izv1gzBfSODCyvbNGZfH7ZXpq2Ny2JHNjauXTOcKDsMzfSZJ8yiD5qmsd14HJOtsCg5TbBybzzSLgHDyM4pj4oRPCgBxjNW741oOAqqLSR7TXv2iVVoX@gI2Hy/hqoj2ippFoow9rZ2ykd0iArImt599kCxvVD3/UDbiZSHw5QFlq8hvkdVsYwOXtrw8v0R7s4a0MFh7I1BJyb2NZNBEyND3sq/uhx@aAUn8vr2ikJ4O3djw@W5H2bFYSi9w/MTT/eKaqZTOZmwuqN88wgM8w0unCfDZV9nVG0wDCFC7mfyZd6y3M1cTMTw6Gb7nW2F/HVE/2FJl1MchdagZKi3YnvLrJIXURXsVwkl@FDt@J5WYwmcrfirSFkZCHFzEbj677Q0HqsbkhX1Uq1sWKKrev24Hok3nU6o4TSpLTGXXZwvRCukx1l1m6lSsa10M5VzXF1ZE7ZZS3RibfmipFt32SHl8vSfLwoxdWuFMtdC4m2qF3M@WVM4y9a1N3sZhhvXizHKXbSX2ZyRr@b8PmYbi47SF7w/Tvxspm76g/0WC82bqa4yGxyKWrL4dWF8lwe5Zoz3qeNiqX4jFLqpdlciHbGPflCuWu02718tj4fs8ad1h9FO5Wp2Uvq8UhkmhGGo2isNDX1ZDmbuUqY@UypXZRv2@bdsp2sU@aFeZNoXfIp2TermXxkmm8xRqi9uJSumvP4RfhGvVAu5dKoPj6fntdlbTrOR6XazSSqD26LPTUcvrhuzi66ZUqPXna6ycYonMzzC565iqnqJHKTqpb1ymKafa4JnRzfzAq9eCgbuy2wo0ptyddm5UajU9c6rUnCuGLlu2JoRNVu@WYmOy6WJ0n2prosJc9LzWkuV1rMemFxoGam/U6kchufl6tCqXPNRC64qVnxSbmazIwuL41lu3VVuq0adzCsK5dSVFwusu2sLj7nc0alUWaq@njYjI6UvtZOSDmVv6yXomZpnLmYd@5SpexYEOu9sTq@6cidqSnlR0yRWubG162eMC9KqzlXiJbb18yo0ODNRGYQaTIjUeyN5ZqxGpyXV4PmtDfop2rnobzwfNXPtmONgsZWika0qiyp7k1WlFaNa5Ed11MXpbteISNVlFiuLmj184vZIhzuSmJ9Hluxi9tRMSot@GioXMveVnzXl@GGr@zLZutqpDagwvnieWcQu/KpRWHFlEXuOZHz6dNpdJGf4hvOyi1F1icxOZQs3viGCUPvpCqVec8o3TZyHV5eJe8q43H8rkHdzkqGqoeTl8VMiqmPQ/o5N6qW7hKSUozOs@dyIVXqrFpJs1CeysmL8iB/2dDzNxP@NlUYNJfL8SB5KdTL4wwlJPONxqg3aPcW3aZRX4YqUX7U8xXOC9XnAYzjdrMYvmxl44NpI9K@yiuz@k3Rt1JvO2UtVx2zhXpyGr9JRCbUbHGZzDRNRdLy55VU/HoqlQuZ/KCVY1VBuH3mr9gx17xZhpJGQr8u3l5rhs@86anR3jAbWV5Xukz7zjBiFxJ1t@jES5mxzl/1F@alkbhRwmrtOsRei9WWHJt1pOduXR1lJsxV63bF9Oar4qJu8mZzrMb6idj4fGE866sr/YpKdkec3Krm1PKIj191pVWCibHKTTcnVvjuZTiUaQ0uKkLxYjZYtYRJeHTxPL3gOd6oZ7q9czk@W2g@MZKclambaud2kHh@DvWEajclZcatRr1khm84ZtptlmPP5a5hFPlWScpGJWWaz3bPx5Pc3ZK7MRar6U28J4vLuh4OFahFtVtp8yN1YBSNO360ui3eKZVpOH5bG4kJsz9mJxJbbouhRFVr@PK@unzeGyzj7akw40Ez1K5LGpvNjEY1qsZOErPsMmWYyrlxVe3lLjNSJlNOhq@1cOJinDu/WPSldqtdvehzavSul4vEa71BKNzPVguDenQySNSriWg5R930ltcNtp9PSuyQk3Ojy2VUS5XD2TjTnjcurkc3Q6Uq5zKdhZiN8DfqPNHhRKUlrOIJphLyjYapSyUTitbjVMvMm61ycR7xKVelSri@XPK3PW4a4cTnruHju6vhqtYWOFUelp8b7E17Ws5Jo1E7nuVvQrVsMzRdGXNOK9epVL6usPnyYlacD5udkKHlL7Rkb1Ht5@p1oaf1I5rYq2UWYmjW6dxdX7dqyuT2enLRSPRqqz43irVNsRGvLUzqGVSe9qzcKvYWedEQR43Zs3K@mN62mWjrfFJu9We@UequO4tIt7VQuZpti9y0dD1ImK3qQqtcyqLMTMK1AUPNW/XVyhQyaqE6r3QXYnu1ykhZ45ldXDFc@byUvzV9qUIxk6/dNDldrtXOy/kMN5lX5uXbhE9YNSv9mDR@vqPqiiKH9bumnMiGIka4FcuvcvzoPDQ9z05uLm9SrMa2LtqVyhU7lPkJn@jW8vFOhe9kMpdXy0uRa9frWv2qdUPVfMrt3d0NU7uRyymxXGrcqLHSTK90OglurmauuVApOunNy4vsvDKddiapS1/XFLiIuhIEtjGXy4xwAbyTpITprJ6r1o1l@Hk1eh7M8uptO5XRzuOZ3FLsz4TZKpTJz3yMUVzM@3FJS4ZvuotzsctXBoOrRnYY0WbaTTwXoy5TYkVp93LDSmopXF2U28WpKTT7vajkM0La6OY60zJa/FI65@PDWcvoyjD4RC12k82lDPkun7zSJV8oyWcpvlPh6kx5GLutXvbVeW5RaS/zYHIkWbEeiqlLpT1NjpWLKyN71Xm@SiYHrd7FGCqeDu@GvNTyZfs94VqUq9Td7VV7XKhP28zo@raSqLcufMlVRD9/5tXhOZda3qxqoZAgpgaz0nQR0cp88jx5VePly0W10RKFQbwZvpbPlRWVVxLDUEZk57O5wviWsWyyMBCzraqi51v8RUJQ6xzDLDp3Zq1zm7wKn4euQ83JPBQ2KnMmJHYVadmtdrvhPpWdGVdap8nOCr4LM9Ntjhr8ucxUO43SSl2WC2GjlanmxKvpfKmVl5IeuePL5zm5zkssqCWx@OBGb41X2VmP6oiLci6bTNyFL4CDDENOzbtRTuANbbAYMeXK9EJejKbjtu6bLJiG7667iKWG7aHB8OXyTbU0L@gx9dIYKVQ8zocvOrqWMBrPk2UpZ@aH7ZYczaXag17tostUbsSr1HWueZcQYnWm9CykOs14iC/HOjzDNtTJzIQZiR@MqfIy1Nd5WdC5xLT2HCtMp77@cjY1fdpd4vwq2RmMc@yM53yRTE995hbtSzkkVRPCwKh15rPbYgc0RKU9aylU8a6lRa6kC7F50a5Vxmw901iZTDbV4W@jg67Oioo4a0TM2GVJGCR4MV@4G4/yF6XnUqgrPofmrKxfX0eKFyyVEH1ZU@3LTPtau1ZWYU7IdGvJyry/yk2GVVG4KIXzercR7zevOLkA06j0XA5p7eJ5@a7fk4eMqCq1ZiMUou7i4ULntvHMzvrX9dWNurjQB5eZuhy5FUuKWr9ts/lrnakmssXr3Khxl1sm43Vd7gk3g@SNMvGdR1SeyyjlOJUQZkK23WFaghRhE4tVjxsLDHvXGY@TF8wqbqyYjGLMR8nBKtU7n7Cdu6p6frMcM@eTxV09e8tOBR/L1nmNujZX9dj5ecd3tTxvlQZyqyTyDDdZjoyL7FS4nPeu4xlfUgvd@Ar99nBRrg@0ToFJ9HpJthmJdKLmc7@@NK6rVDtfvogk8ktzIRbG0@oieaFl4s3lonUdjY7vRotashlvxBbsTB0XslpxEGPUWyOhLG4uBsWsUBArolFZ9fgJFV9Nq6VisuCLCVy33r0LiQXmudmXzeFAvLm6jTTjDB@7qNXnd3f5DDNJiKNCST6HOXHOVRbL5qg77l3XjIhEqbWurxRfxVfNu@tqX6l3LivD3nyQSNT1i/YoNV11tYbU8GmrVqmnnufrEzm/ugWGizdSsVFLLrQ60m2@EapRZryTmYMOzmbL0nLAlGKhK1EJXS4m56nbSSc@7o7buVmjuxiP4s1ETJ0Kq4TZeY5NhVaiezlpMnyvOx/6wueU2lwtbwvXUb1cnWtls64KV6FkuHw3bk0K05Zvkrsq9sxcJ6T1wp3yfOrLxUArSFbaqXC1dzXKlsbn18bFdThF3RSl5TQ5Oo@f@@owmUxHRi3ZlsPyjOkwcns@E8aTEFfNc2190WsVy/1qP5xkNJ@UmJtX8efLbv2OM7WowlDGMt6fc76LAmgQeakba/raphaagC0Sup1FrpRBJGwot80mb@bUxLgVSQnRot5W1PZCHbXD0vV5YjznpasRlRVW/ajcanT61cVq3k@No32uOWtlirdKJ5JTtOHC0Nl46irc5p7rEz1SM7V6ucVnlesJx4lz30LO5it6c0b1B9VMv1N8noqzdrSWiWaWt/1QdHo3G7HK6rbQDY/qvcxQnDc60VVjHsn2z1mlMZG0iR5mQjdtpTBOLloXwhV1uSoIy2HyOltvR1tXo9Q4Ig/GzXpoOa5JIn93Z0zZUndQvmb7pVg7e50aX4hGRki0UuLliFlUe7W7eK4vREOUb1iaMOFcmY9cFm595iUvx56lFVs1VylRWVZbUq85mGW0cn/UmlazF0yWDc/OF7VJ5KLBRKZcdpLMX@ldXaaEQiyzaNUqcWN4lzHbUbUeniW1u7o0uA3360OOn4TiSZDBlX7vbtnKNLLzcrd60TQyymAl@PT5lXJeKhazCnUhdqrPxjOnitNMtFUrd6@frzP64CbWM40Su3gWmOVSqV3meH7ZzZSMcbV92VRKidCkn60krof9stJS61LkiuJTifFtglGa/OU0JETrmWjxuX3OP5dm8YY6Vkz@pnDHmtUGCLtSrFXTuvPJKjcMiYtItHBr1AZ97Q5G62hFhacXjW6/IY6UxbxxabavIpMmO27P5XFc4TRftJCq1Th2EEEjLHarKhNVvhqYt83q7EpnmOEqPhW0c@FKosphbZApNeKXYe78vJtPtdjJc1kIJyvRaWYerjUqPiUmaPnSYCKHcuPGSLiWwGToxOujy1CzKrUGd9PcbWrZpFbdnphSLjtz9So3nufHs9FNaxEB8@qmXTaMZuPW7Jdm4d5lQu7Vhv2bfDF3zec4zkjUlFyhNtam7d5kfhGNUaNi5HZUSVxKg/g4URKW3auplqpfrkq54UXU11Uuk2aXM@Xnmjx6rvZMs/eckNrN60umk03wSuh5mTBvhx3GoC6Sk8J5VEisSkM20VIms@m0X2soamlZv64AmRPhyM15j8loneu62e5fCPztRQs0/UtVKDVvL7Xm@e1Ff9pXKDkC7Jtj9KvzslG8zY/v2HmpsexJrG9cu5rXYomYmOr5ZrFJdTjNx2KdxOSyOivmNT2@qIDUH9SX9bLQqFYodlLpFsa@S5Flk3pl1Z5FGxnhNt6rzMV5NJbPLJRhMtkKLa4vz/nrZE8rzSetS3ZwzczvUmNjwrW4RoZXxRqVfdYiy/zCLIRihav4xe21MIrP@4VpuJSZNzuluJmqip1O9HnemI@FapEVbxazebherF2bSjS2aF/fja@gF2IUP1hcFxJCJSr0Q9LqLqcX1Z7S4jIh5pIJz1vta586UJ6rgm9cDxcjWrwQWtQ5sIzvstPLfrzXGsmd8@xFakj1o3zBd2PES3fx59vniqTfjnyJCYicpNiYXVdAJemZrZvo4lpMddlVO5fscL3iii1cMZnoxcU0VQqHL8upcpcymrEJcMvzPHx7mZfD1/X2TXTqy1fzi/6weddq5OaV5F2XndQ7zdklGmMRJjQXa6NGa1ktLlqSEC@MGwUxS/lK13OjltLERr5d0Jl6XyxGR@OL8@K5ML3ip4uC4gsNSq3l7Hk6EZKXFZkTdKXYMIcZPtJNjiMLvqRlnq/a1PKCK1yyuWQ7qY8l/nJUbRkjY9bRRCkTfY4tfGZjVJeuYvnGza0yag2rVZ3PVcIJQ8iPm5P4XWu06M2EQv@SEs3UjJcX59W4qWSXRem2Vbm@7DdDS76evKwW9UWoxxSfm6GZybSSzfrNoFfVpfIIJk5ft6WqSRlEijlUrylOG5ZC83bmqp8cGLnzULJ8uai1pKovdF1ojPJhY6b7mOGkFs6v1MJlRJwnBo3rq0lIz836Q99VPcHcjbLqvErFzH6kwxnjVENku902oxUaK8OoJFs939W1zAiN8F0ie7Fib3oRrT8ddpPdyfnsudutPPfazQvozlufEG9WnqnB9dWFkRBTPNtvZXPljDrTQpf6pCFGJ2W12wp3RV93kS/Nn8NXoeKo1GOr1eFqleUv9Y6SzE96lRy3HLWSbSpSqIX6dxFBu2zln7vF4XTE58oLPnKrXhi@22h1MT3Xk4k4G03NOCPSnkzavmRGlnyJyHA5DGcLs3ie6euNDlWo@XIdVYVR0LiLc1XGiParsmm0EjfNQqqRK@YuyleFW7Gcapa421tf97qUK2Ru4pdXw3H0qssaWSZbGY6aYWpUzo37jGkmp1JTKhqFcz2/GN6NryfT3jwxKxvdlXLFTaXBhBU5bdwpK4l45rr9HKuFIoUKU7hbyUo4EVukqD4v9i8ZuTG@7SSlwgXTlYdgQOeB/8e3lanOi7oxTHWg5ZWVksi1aoO2fiEP64Ch3JtqvDhJSeOhELmjGkwzWUx05CuRr3Ubk0S3J93eXEYS4nQB9ms3v7oS8wz0eqvbHE5Dt/ECqK7R6HOpM5xcz6ptoxHLt2/K9SjVfm7kRbZUKJfbd2afrdZCg@LMbCWSFwWWn2TH1cIy28uW5kW@1bnwjXzhmz4/K7YzcqHd54zF8i6UCukZcUTFR/FKVsyz5jzWFvVo7nJYi3BySV3ULpPapFG/DGcvC9eiOtZD2euM84m3l6mJFFsOxEzmvF3q5gZU5jqXH4XbosE3FN@8RMCyRZn7w68@KkTQdYWAUTNV6tPk9ZL2MRcnXzl4gpw8gY@375w7gc4@2wcJiPbz1YAL1ON3tfAJ4WOrErK3GcQjoHFr8eT13mKAdY4TIBc8x4M@Isc@izsboS4dM6/R@CgpX0OA7HiSHRTcByOPJ/9gHMMXcPA7RQKZyBN1HkIb7zdxIxTBcz5YPCPr8WRry9PDbmODCEKXcYoI9PS7fsBTFX6EjGQLuFArevdt64dOdvIDcoamkJNGXIGgi2S1T8XAknaLsHoT49dnM1DkQBZnY@0rL7XgGDYZiqfI@R604jf9k/vUo/@IT7towZQ4ZWJM9Xl/PFCHM5GWaW3UW/DL1TNNx6J0BOoK/0j7sE42nmbIsYUJ@E3SqZB9IhP5fCInauGxVOTgNzw7103TgfWpTh9pLwn48efYdfKGS@mjicOF1iEfk/v4Y1pJh04m98rjieLzeU1f2vSxPg9G/Mh6T7Sp7Yl4bz6Sp/aZI7riPFqPRz6j768q0nVV4Yeq26DJy9@2nzkhh285A2jCadvjaSbwpqpvx4jIT9xkZyC@jcJdYu5VTkl14MylJuDW3fpUAhnfiok/H6bx6MnbdGzhhw94hMaJ7Tux3YAvlDbtyRJ/TH0g9MQtcHyc/vjYPhSGxzPNcAMN4yQr0sKFlgwPJp84qbyqLe3MkgXy5LTldKvIMw/urXr93wPpQPWAJ5/wBR06gFkgFnl3wGkommyNei2sMFwWlPU@KJ7j4z3BU07oj06ac@IPwiPfkHN3nkxaIqf0wOWUtkHJGRi01z5xgsTeS/jQG3ElOHNbSR9G04lG9p@DFr42RfCVXk8aJ@nrnEFjiq8P99AsEkNykMYewMALHoE240xhu2ucvkDHN/LwFbYHy6uTI@QBYZ7T9SXKRnz4AMvrqyTPB@udcR7aVC3HSgsNOy9phtfuaiAcHirq1tzHNPGDO4EosiV6spU6glRs6zvJE0iecObwneQhlj013kvWIRnfJPdOsgTJ1jOR@9NVSLd2@t8BMNHLE9j1yVSfTE6SPdaBHngUyIslsD20z@cQds0CtNUxVn/s5qfto1Hoj1bvWMy2w14wPglbWQDI0h578OD9hltIKp656rH4YqtOiyb0F/qbldnOkUDiJ1ITiF2s33u0Uz69hQCMPxCl9Nt0p3Krt9cN3eGfIEw7A@xtIFaE/uWXr2FmM@Iu/7GPDvdZPYR@uFsttKi1Kcd61damX61MKzvT/jz20THb0s3xkdi0wxmU4Y0IscbWZlyLktKHOqDgj9vR6PLkpT9tYu6NR/p4LT02dLSGxbfpGH7DPegRRUakn@5tgvz3U5VDvoecHMzIvY2wwHPCuJM35DTW0IFd6DOAXlPzFZ/xOzxjj9Jf29jva80B4EcGNaHNiSVoeVANz2wE96DHWf26LROswg7dx1Y8vkFM2i1Meqcw6zy9JyjAPAUccGZzxLgzJ0pK0HomFeR8KBz1ExdzC@RlQyZHWH0Pnf4JBhcSzp6yp/hSlV2RRO8hzRvwdbuRXmevh9yr5lmSfn/j7q2Hmt2f3Igj/ZafCNd9glnymA7R64ObTuiXb8uhfxhlvmy6b0ffMTzvywqn0x1O/B4WfHmH0N9kst0mhB/pHYpPyYuYtW9OSeQQwv2T0sa1/smJcdwurbH9rgaGWJ3spiPOVoFOAijK27n8ts51thGd9umLT6aj3Pg3Whh59zfhClDZT6htcY7mXJFM3tux66OjCEW2U/BJdtQwdQczSXR0W1CDnXxB/gm72SIy0hPG9EBV@x5HYbIVBlKCc0IHAPmt46zWapWlXm6qh@pspZce2Kd8OPPuCcR8tKPIvAIRqHzavIlIHA3IsDnBYbOl30gGedUeScfZCKpynj5AZ0VL@tDHr@MReq0CfdibyZH4eCYZObnSlvNkJt4RD64cp6BjKHaHZVqfujB@3REIcwaG9uZ8S9IHL3tWGawzPO3TLb9smy7SiRREnXjd6Y4XpPdkjc3pqQurWTP8yx8OPjJTQ2d6ksIIyozG921TB7SgWG@YOca3AAeS6CiML/G1pQnxyyZOiMAm0FNYW1AR5h77Rb94iqjLS1ln0hGnRZbCc3uJ37gszPqg9VsntmiqsSC/SzAWQsGpZqokxa6InF1H/yL9sjlPNUSeIrItBhudU1LOBsaDzxdYsUvLVzLAWgoSi4cSe7eKuMecROC6Hlwu7D9E1PYnvX@kjKDA8UNEAnnvF8ucgu4inPxCGU7X41lrSAp8eAWCsnXKhEZ8R7EKop0YS3IPzcd7FgNWDHFxRb637RSKOARjiqyqGjI5uoJi/lMggEX4D82bfKHRCNrvGLA81tHL3fJjxkcEyYF19ku6bTde9FbH4wKtTvmAjcWyrfrSm8KJ/CU0wmptMuFQmCM5LVrheYRWCwIsuXvTjDW81wInJCGPO9l3BtIyZJ/qoYEehbTbZPNsZQs42RzgLVJ8@CY1OJ7HgyAqwkQFjHOCLAPSFi0@bMiBQaSIU79vXb9xj3U@rpG30gNv0gM76UEr3UJqAxXkh/oG6HgbyHXwZQP3Qrs2YP43daVpaHSpSk6XCqr6Ft4nX4M1gmCkSRvgs3VXWly5TjjdSQhspfy0p/etlI87edYMvk6/t9Jt/g7bPb/Gcgf28279eKXsDhLIGQz2I4uvuDSoSLL14vhNCpGwNB6rZGXH/iZsZw1Ke0HEFicBEBP4Mm0ctmfpTSk@1pE4ZMy4zk4/u4L2ktQnz2s0rHfjvBlYe8bIFpVInT5CuAWZSaAekvxxqwhSJjIa7YzcMyfz0s683CoWoT461VLOSaG7Axya9nqIp9Gt@xf8cQb7LnIO3MH@xA8W5gur8daTFrsEIkL3o2s/mXalialPBSvSbtRXZpFN3cvXJe4XElUVLVB@SN6Z7tQpWM@DiOpU6X9cy4ltQeFIijd0X6fYlN4AsA77vteFmPhC/f8)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)

### Explanation

TRANSCRIPT is a language that is meant to look like an interactive fiction game.

I originally tried using  an NPC to hold the data to output but that was unsuccessful because NPCs can only hold strings and was causing trouble for Whirl. So I ended up using objects because they can hold integers. Because of Whirl I had to generate 120 by addition so I needed to use 2 objects instead of 1. The code to do this is:

```
You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPV
```

This has slightly more than what is necessary for TRANSCRIPT but is needed for other languages. `You can see a y and a x here.` declares 2 objects(variables) called x and y. The next 2 lines set y and x to 88 and 32 respectively. `>PUT x IN y.` adds the value of x to the value of y and stores it in y like `y += x` in C. `X y.` prints the value of y (120).

#### Brain-Flak

The reason for the trailing `<`s in the TRANSCRIPT code is to keep Brain-Flak balanced.

#### Trigger

X is the symbol we have been using as the jump for trigger, but all ways to print in TRANSCRIPT conatain an X. Since I didn't want to mess with the top line I decided to add a second jump to reach the end of the code. So the target of the jump is now `V` with the start of the jump being the `PPV` at the end of the TRANSCRIPT code.

#### Underload

Adding the TRANSCRIPT code broke Underload. This was fixed by moving an opening parenthesis from just after the rk-lang code to inside the evil/Alphuck line.

#### Incident

`V` had become at token so I added one at the end of `x`s being used to line up the Pyramid Scheme. I still needed to destroy one more token so I moved a space on the evil line to stop `<space>se` from being a token.

Answer (score 6):

## 121. [Braincopter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Braincopter), 4410 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉QQxQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoO\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPV
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #7E7E7C",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #00A2E7",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002489 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4519 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaLEm0iRFHXZ2iAIkCBBAALA69o60X6Z6W5P2OOedkdPz7jPdMc4oiPsp3E4YhzTEY7wvM5XnB/w@YPjzALAi0SttXZ3UyJRqMqqysrKysqsShR6nDH8wx8O8EPXVXk5kFWTNgXDpPu6NBP0IJ1d0p85yYiFIxSFUBl9MJ0IimkcUwc0S0sKL/XhljbVsaBIK0GH6DCt6epA5ya0OeRMWjB4ThMMWp2a2tSkVXF/rghdmKgjKYAZJ5IyAChT0DVdMElylG4pMjfp9blXCbHd2jQdkg06L8i/TH4xaV6dTDilbwBgnM7XsoVy5lX@BF1RdUPAUnjBMFSMS9KLgsC/AkzRFU6X1HKmer6TYhGmrqv9KY94m0MB0rGpoiQLBsUDVme0ZpM3iAH6gNYFrm@BUaKq05iFnoxlWqJ5TaN7MjcM8rQsAWwxlKQFJA29gvQD2lAnwjYCBq0IQp82NIGXRIkntdLCwhQUQ1IVI0hL/JieS7JM9wUZMmxQ4f1QGD01tqKsioNUX6Vo@PDaK8TXd4cCwCiC03hBA9pg41UkJFDCocFc5zQNkAQCNgFxU5oAK0im26AFzpCQ1SCLISh9QjdtzYQqzSnbraRnEkdzgO9UJ2Ubgm5C84KkXHoo6AIUya15wTPXJRNIgGTN0HWB0@kbXRC8uyy5UyVUpmINJjYkSLrt9NRdqBXd0H1WjiCnmdSBHrm5vqQ4OpimD59O4Jt2uU6oQjVPfzl8wLDFhNDFmu7hvHT6N7TBPDwI8F2wPWagv1BQKgVUkWlG1UyGC2iAYMAEBBkOgxgKzMJBTd6qmD591RdbTGVB9aE36JJCt/2kZfxU13GUbYjKjaHRsqoMgJ7QWH2qID0UOh6CLuBVGCd@WpgB1VTF6iN1Tih8M5Sg0wzsEq4HBOJ4pL0lKQhBQVYA79kUdeo1VHlK4CCnYSIDAlUgK5ZYEuk2LXKSjFkgHYuysNYFYyqbmGeq9LHnQRgI/SDtoMGrfQSaqDOojoNCSQSMocnWyCNIATB0hEqaikm/@9f/rj8YQDkZnlf1vs2ubbqv8kSmcQRZkBY0MqyqcDJBC@D8WLuVHSqYcbLU50ysXlnaVRAkSK1zdSr3aRUq1OcSDK0hN4PhKIoCbwoWk1uC0E9PuLElLySLc6HhE64HHUsqIHWTZgfozznoJV6gDgjPBCZTU0zSAa1Auw3mJ8@nY8@njw8CIOcNeo8OGWZwAgwXPCJRcOf@Gue0M5sOhboMkzNUqU9pS3OoKmE6wNMuPq1qguJx75Th9rv1ntsbRDnm8Z5IaT4oSkrf4wYez0K9bu8Jn@bvpePHk1e5t2uEUuZYCo5WwcN7XRRIHDImZsyEk5SgtqTbATu0laYaT0hxTA5uRSNdXsfNrIgDMhUgW6rIHyCGgoYsCJonFGS9KCUQbm@zMWFfQ1@VYTf4WHr0uQ/cvu2mkxKgpTsNxbF6I6kotWRtOAUZDURRDA2kt46sy3PAPAYKcROmYj/dI2xNJD8IFiIS54JbF@geyFGHjciItEYc5g@gnLRL2IwgB253QAv9rfEMsgCGtGm8EcqyOoeKCW44bYEEUbBybgBdBJmtBmWsBlk1kpjdpo0VkCtYWk@gk4GeBGMBRx2Idpv1t9oI4JGwBQOlWWNlSwRNuCWUwltT4mbc0JIIQ2oCUkJf0ryAogdkkGDNK1jJlAxDA9QQVEhCgXAstjvU3ow0U2cygTuQ1SvmqwMKG789plDe0KIwp2VOGUy5AWpCCmTheF7QTFteQUsMEyTS62mHRAbsOTRoDKnDz6/rJnOJPbtu1YGy3uo9e0bkUMjY6lBABplKc7YuR/clHaSTvHxdOwDMXlXu@hlBdhD42fUOCo4iAEwmLAR@aoJwA0aeDyV@CLyL2CmWeLTmotfVQ9R27SDgA@K6akSGPfsxTAWZdRSi8W4RAezRt@XAHItFne1EkM7fjvh6yZwx2VOwukYR5oOt2CDDBYH3bKKB9tREzQ0mG0dVIiNrrc6t6QkEhqEOwxSYZWiamnEMsl0yh9NeELqVudGXJbOmYM8ypr6UTNUK92S1B7LUgMHEODUw/LQnLV61iMStCT4yqBkoTaJBp2G2fZ4Ci3jcogFSjsTnEHgryUWkLSnC@nUBIAEKAqU8okHkZxEkQHOp8B5XkPB9EEaIy0@7cJS5vBDAXGu65NQJigy6QyZz1M6yOogZEUSLLaiJnOb2Tk9rgU10Mbc7OFIlxfPF/fHjR/ex@wzE8cePnyB0iqFPGPJB6BMJBUgI4YIYIjn8JISp9yQHxj26X@6dkhfeR@y2BU4lK0nzcPfHx5FHP3fP2tcwXr0gl0AMAXQAL1CO25tOY9DrdZ3NoaHBnmi1vmFRtk@4oSEoA0pYaKpu0tVavvBUz9xcpF3M1NAZWeoxCkyGTxMYbmBwuPbkB8vByQ7BhqqaadJhGE@giwBk20yUqU5hgIKxIE0ks0RMFFlB1t50mpOag3qtAkrbBomoq5O1eDEogR@qtOsw4kJFesfIwznXTo1i6tS28bbiExg/QRMtyFMDnqcDqnW7jrQBkwiIdlsQLChq4PMhJLHj1pE2ZIoUicZcUO9Z6O8xDW3gOAL31Z4gL@LRgCCLQXOxCuJIjEcp60IH@u9B7MlLLVb7MlAmDKvAQnyVwDkG5g3I8jKo7nRZMogVvU1xas17D5TLGhuRXSnt2qSENyrVfj3QtV0K4RPoq7GKkmgTegKlJ7ZTBJivb3OKkjEkPzugbzB6m0JyG5OeSH72ABzbugUoKmjoIkku0UxC9UZVwSieE7CJqqgWKkAqSeGYBrkEYUrah8@u5N9BpieIUzCdmJ6kYPgbYIFUkkCKvZ70HijQBVF3rnvA9GlvH9mAuYZvlAN6h/DmVDdloW9f/9sf96ED3nbPkFuCys@P14EnoBt2VUB8t7fsrHhDfvb3LIEZTWWJI2QgoW8VyXNolnHyOrC/aJR2dCAw5HTo3KXTucCc@AMz11f4zMJcF@RpX3Cu@yshJN5VQazcijQhLYIr6lNkinon@ysFysqPZq0uq1yflGItN0jCpretfhEW3AAax2xJJBBW34Gno@fQm/UF0BHMqfWLSwrf6ldJw@/XxqsNGYpxPVYAY4zrSe9QEZGIv8fX1nDBOT0gytzYCj5hcH9Trcbo0mAAuox9fQ8MtEwwBDSOF5g5ubwrYpSpoVldgaGvlKfL1u97IM6y5jrwHiA0UyY/v4btCCPwMDYQVVzSC2yRSHpFVJnrLVHvGf56/sEKyeQJ4iXN@3yhCM6jaxtws3ioae/nx2ma5E@l9ue21hlJAbwqioLwrTEL84404eRAuL8VfFcEO3riJrQHdMTNONAgZc4ABjFtMgsz6Bby8zWmxamEn8qcvgl9hWU36Dim/nvW4iaPJvGqLNmc6dy8Jwtfq@6bYnAFmfxssuLdW/r2QVvGaTqwDu0f0CpvosX2Dh99h3iyjCU0R7cYI6i@RzteneP33dE7VGeC9bt/ylrtxeo7xE9AJpwBFtjb7H3@W@yKS3/kZz8Vx3uxMnl5b/wxXVFVHaxlgw4HQ6jgKGS9GiZsWbYMwptS7X2eNiRZNegm@f0aLUArNwzrdz83b5NN4pQAP7TG2Dq8P9tepMj0RmfI7zudy8kDVY4nBwwHP@9ywFQXUcrb1@@VcGsJxbLflFBrdUdVWPv6rmgfw/@3mIOsROpo828Fv6JF7RNntq34fgPBIsBVt/2NK4aSJGeQsUyp9zpA54dzbulc/xGzx3vUdWYPbUmUZdDmMEMqCQFTtxTof0xt0a/X1v8@GfWm2MS3GrHVuWNZAIlNft90KR0Osb8yBxsKfb/EEuWpMBX2SpBabyQA23xNdnw/UiG7GYf2YgIDxMPNyTXUyjYFvwtrnM/x7qsCh5MlGOTf1Gb2ihoNNGwNTec6BOoYeJtxoEy1nc7dol1jqjS@Trmh5oxstb@DJKb8WomU/LbOtKOGGwL57hcgx7itDgavOgEdQvmO/rcLJes01u9OwSRmU/JIwiUg/avlHtPrxUHQX0EfgV6VxkYA15G@T/CE37PUCXAqBbaYIphL/H2P2vsEaU9V5V/TOyBP@xKqaaB84i79t3rpmG4uJz3Q3PjNyuV39IBjJgK10CR@t2PrUKT5nWVG3i68fWWW2lqG21vzuSqfnZ59o9MbOHbZYDKY@Cqgs9zFOIF3hiApLBWMfI/6ozk6LVmkxIVNaylz401w8Eq8aEsgjNQPGPxQmAjk9isKPdcfTQ3n8i7QQsXvnuQgQ5Yl9/apJJjfoGvTVBXB@CoQaZezwLm3ntKEGwjFb/LOZgkBN/B4XdoJ7l9MOLaYnYdsXxcM1jI18UFYb1MZftt5AuIk3d4qN9b@KAclhdcFsmnl7IvQB7iVNp2ADWaqepAmcB4P5/N5vZSVCdX4gQJgDhTxCMBtQsvZwKDBuDIJrCTS9/f04ZfFceiYfaHTtOvYRT8@WqWSDavCQiNb@Q0r6/0h95g@dAcC7kP3g3JMh9wEVJBBq9oLyu3AiRK5WHhumk4r3ITsTGLYaemJtf0Jxg56GAw5pS8LdAvEBDEBVd3axLN2im9w1e@//n3fdrwYCNDIiWTALDpQ0FlInQhDdf7JqteuPaNpHDpuYBnzIS5rYe2BXIY25pIJA4P4W4At1ireJO3tW9uNCW7qyCtbWFidihIKnQpMq9MsbPqqYHGFXfE6l9MosHanE4WeS31zaATBclF4gWwPr/cUIIRgiqmryFV@ukT3BVx16SNiZFjKqjommx@IyX/9e2vTGhIlZCEMO9UTn5WtGmkUNWSnmOfVKWDtFLISdNUG8SCRwWaf4oQGPC1Y8V6aH3JkNx04MeDsJWM11n5yLtOkAwXajT5XuOl1Iomew0zjvH0fekz/hp4wwn/7Y8b7xaab64dAgjVcftoBOXlBvtpODkHyJtVNuw4XLrtZ6N1DnFnWTGV74HkwTLrL2RueEMcgwnfCnOwNEwcABec69LhRDBgfcOslRVuDJn3omVriNdA06Rg6poHo4iBkuRIRHwvc58Qshwv6F3qIvBLgaTYWgjuLIDJurU/SWWfNPLK9rcHkhd6ULPLNwsFwJE2ac/iUhqkHQ7rQV9HT5f6nh/kjYzhUeXhY/BAKL4Bsqg7gPzI4cgrV/JfD4Fnol18MsGNcrhf3ibW/A8P78Eu9VC80bzI3rSaQ8cVq5UFR1SfcRkQgE2gyWJhDVSa@Q0APXRKMb4uND0RuUB9sQI@HPuToU9DsaZBQH9aCxSarK@A6tIJWGpEk67RXibb4ECXaFnV0nfS23bFuY1vM@R0GQOLBmJyCXHWQB8b5skdckea46DQ0KAANIuBrhNd3@xq2m0rgLYJ/wnsgut2MbSjS1A3UfiBsqwVs423BWEjubcTLPxPmGswj38Ycob6FOQBT36p9q@JiplRuNQpv696q1oZ5A7LmkC13zcIC5nCQgyLhcMvxy@Ib1XYycgQDyP2h5YrAyRvRZtAzyZB6skA4SUTBLMPYxkFBltoNHNw0ypEgnZENEKT9PkiG3tJEwQISNUg2V60d1oBCuw6AAMH1POenXRTCGum3ziYgOOagifM/W5kPCRwp2aD2OMc9CMzv/vW/sxziHkwI/6kdFiH8r6zwTwwS6K1Tj4XjmjRIlnapThswW1kNn3CLrTbhhIETkqSABS5NgIIzQhAEt5DdtHdTjue@DfSETgBiouRDYUfqE/RHD3p5HDMMzu8DVRaDZINOWEA/gKwkTh/PU3RQBPnMxGPxKMsAkoGZU2BAsgoMaFaBXu8xsBA1k7T0zz2ePj09pV0GWGRCOn5iEZI55H6KuH5eI3oIsJSlCtzTkAeybHJA2pmdzXPI@VgvZsVR6Gbd9OMJzPJWv8BE4SEBAPFitGLTwwUzkWqTCjpdERYmEapLR8UB/UIhm/2C5abqFBSAgqyy0Y/uNe9udn5wP3yLm4Pb3eDqIFgTwY5d@1jn/if6wXxQHm13ShoY5j/sYSQFwn@2x8dyzT2Zt959nte@edga@nNTUXEvsAjY0p4wE44wbNy7NVJcdlGAL46LX6BIGAkwsnhBGqmakckVSpe1evONdxqBdL8Gc9Pus1PfQyDov39cB9yvuN4harbINCvZokPKbaw2RjVCbCzr12juq@01pu/U3rG23d7WTRLeVMSGvrdgYqkEimTx6W3pm1RmCzBnbQu8qdXj/fJy/3h69qAcvKn@l32OuwfBI2QuCD0YxG3XTe@ROSVnM/EGH5Ywgo5fSti1cUtfO8ZY95vo933W1o9ebDzXnG1L9FsLn4H1PGOUqSxTwXc2NKHtQcaqijhtWYg5@IKscVBlEdVNhTz1ZlNoGxvabsvbp0RsX581kWqWdUgcaDkFDANd4i1ogwhoy4Yk3p5gRZTMjeEBxgyavsS@WhJbAkTFepOlL5HNOE53nJDWKU1hIgVuHHxQcGz80ECQoX/VENomS70TLn2/oNduOV9zUQsamiyZHvQNWwTRRoPWeLzYAPZUFtC17DT1aPux0Y67mY94rNWnQK@6qtEbuzgvOKEGmEZ0fgqFAxsI9OV0AnAiuTQEnCUEuqoGIDPQ0e0gcQ@1eOw2BCf9GNQeHAqLvjSAmcbj9YNI@oFlN75unNcH9qwb5LBFqnPcPdomzK/yz9uiGHfPBSWlLyw86Dh9/IjUgXj3vDNze11veIA4Cdoeg/3X3oKOsOBMe9RuPO1eCYRUai0IdsdOKhUcGhS6TYF2DzU2Tb0MQZhDPeKE02jPlLhbGnSQJreeB4/iN0zdSwfOcD6b0wrt8xG7AC4kIUiTnCIJSTKulnjwiQIPk4Z@xlhD6eNlJWn0PRsMPkKYVOKlD9Gkz4G6gcawlwIlErIck2JhAoa/Y8RoDhYQYmRdD0m1FNrjOkDtTSYDeTAkAxBoQVpNn/1Ib6TBZgRaVE2lju3e2BWHKRrY4nSPxIBi94g5R@ME@tq@L0A1FGIAlQNLTwKB8vlKUBQYrx7gmQmMTpqbApPpXr/zjJp/86QEqeHAQvHCdqYBRHefoCi4v8gq6DOHzAkxK09eYN7/@QEnftGe@pfMHzFB5uSL51BOLxlQxrxnnsNhmvVFjny@Q@XIc6igOvLjj2iNvhyCtvMUdAVdCwAKHMreE@Bn0I7Sh8rJIXfqOeynw0ckB9z6fN4vkOE3BhP8csi9MIc/gjbhhxjdGp2eQ8OLwyEUDLIvgB@OkEPGDzzzxeOiXQt0hMfqDyWfD3EIHj4hAr9hHpo@Mq88NBli/57YSi4zmDhiZFdXWffEm8fmLALa0cdriR4jTpHWsuqTA7z9AMWetH360R/@cMDGwdL7FI941E/hyMejA/rgs4s5cumuLw/52Yn7nhPDwefH@rhev/U@eNwHuZqLjbqgNT@d0EcMdcAchX5JMMzPP/8M2id9fxY8Cz567wPux3vP4iyRODrxx5NH/s9@1u0/OaBlNsSyXk847GXohyb9kOC4I180/Fk5kSRJM/p9@KpDfJwHNLE0cskH@HjYutsdi7ibP6GH8KdPH@GP/MNnfYu/H0mMHU1A3n4@emnP84I6OPtwfb24XnzP5wm@tSwJthmWDT@gxRaJf/z8AZos@Mjn@PgzsWNoVyLpUtXPCEwPD1g2RqsHMPMtBLpHLxYB/FAH/GJxsIJE9mAJfyx@8gdPBwuaOvhNOu37zs9iHQoGn5wQdfDz6c/pf8KHOgA74@Ds7PHlxRe4D/6EhT/6Ar7T@9PT4NnZ4izweHZPHXyhDhYv1EHYBezycEQdpBenDYLBff7MxuXZNoLLED4NPN5r9XIh0yz4w6eBg3Axk/OHm63sAQt3sc0tJkbwtlHI5GutG3/YynVeahdadYg3Hp/OPn/2BYGQn4Nnj4DK4gffmS9tmiZ993QUpL/@ebIuzDq0TqAO8meLFhM4BXTLdkyD1BN4gLsHL9T2C3Vwf3Dv@RT@FA7JoVmIHbPjilrb/NdqEC8tQiNVDw1DQ7YPXbsICa3QMrRchCZqje1DUIC/0ASCUkhchAYhJaSw7E45au0hWovXPr@KXP9PamqlpkKBKmQ2FyETyw6JcB3UahUoUoTqR/AnhUKI5SI0g/@QTHiN/ekp5A09PFD3tOtnAcZukHUHQ@5g3O2WHmNx7fnLSzj@fE9m9ljq8V5YSOaji/a7nx7uU6mU@/HkgDEeHhhLnLnCUdcJgry8PD3lMzeZpycGFzoWp4e@z77AZ/ikz3yn9uXTQf8MiRo8/fhAuT3zTqeD3858NrdCJGDFddaJ2zckAJ/ZO3l3A4v9bODx3Mcev7x4vd4PD@4Tt9USj4cWQF/1uNiHRVikwy4vUWRTMAuwEdQ14jHv2Vk8BvfxpDfgCZFkK8uDS9O0B1eQGMZBsgWeTmd0nVsSoChMRA8uTn96cN2HH9PpVIxExwKpOK3qgVTE6/J6f2JPT@06wl6IdrkXLlV3019etv88X15OPeTjxT@vFyPt3zOvB5K9MbhbfPEsTj2nHoyDKMz15eUMgwTuC4TuPd5H78uLFQe/Hu@pVeaZF2iH1v8/479q0IZGuw9eDlCBUOhozOvpLQVvNO5J@lL2X/ojNMDjirgj0C6Xm3Pf338@ihwlovefHo8ejzynR8Gjh7PHHfHsdR/QwMsO76XZA6QbdRA8abjYsMuNvHiCq@iqLARlsO4jqZNdZnA/eY5ef5Jsynfk@3x/lEpZdR8d/fKRpr1QHFTmgs8B8C/toU/PTtdMtSnSewbfL7RNZAi/fAE@s9JAH/HYy@UPD4tQiMCf9NKHXw64lxNSPP3icp/ssCsp3uM@Ifsori@uQ06/Zx9dL67DL70X1NuOWC9RD2LRk5OjqBVOJE9gmmaP7JQQpHitFcsYpAgGx5OBe3KA3OQGknuhUemeMJBgitN2aOSLxWJMGH4XP8QL4QV1gvsN1uaGK@Cyxg@dTJHyDmjDSFFgGvSg4@d0IgQToCxzOq2K4kcrHmwcuicIoGYKsowrdWgCgCYs9@dgdn6kDkDOgAJsCPCZ1DlhKgjz6XQurD85yTjmRrRnBCYsfn7/27/6F/D9e/j@uXX98/8jFcPf3//2f/7ffvc3fwuR/wW@/zd8//Pvf/tv/9j6kvt/gO//sxX3D/Z3C876UlDW//D73/7F3/3@t//qr@H7v9rfv379/d1f/ifr//@1/zD4t7/7y3/AH@sGyvqrP/vdv/0TQPEvMfwvIQz/dvSf2sGtWCv4p04Q8v37V8B/9vvf/pu/s8N/sg2yFQ9Z/xTi/2Yr/k@prjqleQ47Q6A52pJYHBh8@GB/kD6lzpqFG4i@qdHJ5Pp@gfeRMLmvt/C@VKWX5PYWr/V6m0Im@UjHEn5/MBiEH7z6yYdcg4c/OSDs@xP3AVXBRcgUa23JSpgDQrqQwk0o4K25QvYAe/hc6VR7PxIuGIVBXRoMwfSZq2sAwzBgUllPMm@mnA51Abw8wYez8CleE7VfsIpDVBA5PxxOJWPJVCSc9CdTyWiMjcdifjbsZxPJRCrkB703ycaTsRTrT0ZTkWg0mvLTbDiWSoCVpPQlkWFAh2JdLpoEJIXHRyNO8RkTNTg8ow76ggim5wd64el7Pxz0nQh6mqRdkeRDiHYxDBjXQ04/Wtw/pr@4whE6ATXQLO3yU64VzdMHiQL85fC2h7fZZCITj@DtE96CnhDKhfC2T4BDyWI2gbeClZoJF8itiLfFYi5ULOJtzbrFD94undsQFOXi4a4nc/wYwgMID3QY8hBekPipAEEVgugNoZgcKZ0Xlm8/Kyup911JtWWtX@vV4GMlDQZOyqC2/lhJez8kSRRVgLLUfxWvT7WF@mQn1Zwk61qr8U9PrpcT7AGyROGhvfQX1J48tCGtBOBVT8g/BY0h9mmadMUTruMjuLo@uSIQXHjokBvmAJf7weXy3qceP7kSMdcxmDoB94/sJzAoUq5jVyLhgjnCFQZGirlccTqccLnuQG4Kg4Cb/uQ6eQG@cRhyzVE0qFnBIA1fMDowXUtb@HhcKQ9NBGzqwWVNP5Ysd3vc7kTY7fa6T6CQj7Rraxh6T7Bx0DaraQ6CLkAJEEyBtnSiC@ZUVzypAMzldCDlPXmxUPrvtnDSx8eGyem4WEGqPKZd8ZQLowHkNGXVdRbrHR372YD/M2XNLHGWOnih@uiFH03RJ6kTtEBA4zk9s7G7opeJge9iC98T6tCNGLsjOzrgAfk9pGnQ5QMRNaoeHB4egtFzc@aKuGrBp1PGNl/OGGK3PJyd@NLRnI9YAkHHOjojJsTrTzRK6QLuTffxIBJLp0zGkC4D2jiA4k58/5hPEOpNQ6HUCaodrgPNUnyWaGvSDxaup785IEonXf/i7D1OFbKQelzBbuOOm@RZp/tH2vubqiR/SUYCZ2TZwQPdRENHvTRTPyV@Sv5UadVateLn0HHyOPnw8NaAog6MX7xqjP2NcnlycKy5I1F3BMyj9IHVXjbhPTgLJ4IGtzx4tJ1qPNEE8A8N90T5CLMHYmf3M9@5mU2IDQk1Jf@oPxhI4T@q/PzLIcO43TTNHsZ/Ezi1/k/hJ1ezqnDFYy4vOhsZPz399HQApnSKdoVjyME@hraUhG2VxrM4UsifcGSQP0HYRBhw69xhuuA9YhimHQYxn0rFk/ED6g8M87VtAkhdr5uJgqAb08m@hbOMLlU4XFRU1otnEKhMV4IOV@c4EGc@oHFCwJVhnBG24@xJYiuKnKKzG7c0GHQFwliKwpBEzliiRZQJHlSQTbLJTB/hGUboAuWlvlAfoKwpbxIvIvg5oagPuGmOtx4Hzk//aJhe3HwMeakPHywpAMBBw3zCwjGTHRlgT6gXCsnD9fsGjWuaZC/R8pvicLta1SwnT3lJW5kMIkWtyY24PGG9Wwgf0aKFBbTmiCY1EsyxcVb1Hyyw3lREVIqlcgHy0GlaJGvjdm6X3sMH4EnzPopeu3I6BFFYCoITShFwBITiINJDyvZO0DmL9xBIH81iukjW2AEKpno/wcRPi3bGe7x9hOxYvMjLqgEFW7V7rBbQR092tXYbbHxII4CE2DoikDHA6QPeb/cePvZ4/wgzkONe4sFU@pQOe9cOEXZZ0BnWQVMkIz/pW4xDThawyUxKYx/90LUnli@DZw1nx2wI9UIdmf7JidVV2gl15eG9X3AN9uQ3kx9/5H/S7iePJ95J2sSrzzeB@WHskSyQIzM9SQN7aPfS44l57/NJj@mJ98qD9zD1pEMALFrENrx226DlShpwwX0aw@tf3SuB3yiP/uK94gOUp/6ju/TKz6VD/gV8pTTrl/3PadZuB9Rpplc@5YQ7hS8uB@/4i8Bc6eNOdl1IIMvYI6dX99xjGughQ0afrwiNATyNe9nne/RC5TIkvs14Iv/4I@eTzxYnciDgRaifIp@K9yYEHn1pvD/2cKeLT6v7KeQ/9sA1DdXIXkAe8tm0flnjDvidAI2tPt2gbuG4QPQWgN4knT66@3R0d5T@@HF1vwhMHv0W@Y9DG25A5BeI/AZrYMOjOy/9iiTEaPW4fpCOfwgeGaBZSj4fENmvbeW0MDy6gxQNJjwb6xeUl@T8G2erATnM9h2xTiwgD1QT04Mc02OQo8nMPjqxQd6MwUuSDW55H2oS6PEcuuL6wcxUAhyBwDT7PC5MfFh8@kQ5VduODVAzCpce2jpgD5DjWHQ0ocnZbpZz7bfk6z4x7MjctXLeLN0VaDAEIvGt4UpEExlwhs7fIwiKgS@hlxNLYlnuLCBsiPQAGCI9EC6AUgSJZMsJGzJtJ6LOaXcQ5EI5IVoewPg8voHyCcTbZuSDCLHQgMG8Bw3JP0oT2QT8JEGIlk5JfRCAoUJ9gEYgDtgG6ZE@A0FG//gjbd@epsH0SOBcgGAIN/KxCPQGU6j8OzCFMhDLEfAoykNSCeD2AVPQC2unoug/rSLbk9EDGXwjv@XQGAzfuvy4pWdYDrxIN6@FBvbFhw8jUBFthOCf6MeQH9Je/nBgT/fHdK5WATu50KhkmvDLhqPJzZFfx@vDod6cMqPh6TE9SSEuRzzXYIXuJQ/6C2h7wFJqH49@69OXrTIYodW8H59yAtIfWMY8TKjH65IEg5wdYQRVfcDMpbHE7B76iMd0Ee8mcr5kwDmzC9Ehk7O8cSveeBUbaIvDZG4/mrFzauBEMAz78JyAc3ggOSCROFhP0E8YRqF92A7ZOHb2vshOK64e@cn@PZjrEjkRbmgVsJOfnItiWtnJ@KDwkJw@Z3LI0VQqGQod0yE/BlgnEHYCEScQdQIxJxB3AgknkHQCKTvAOiWzVslsOBmJxDfBxCaY3ART62A0tAluSoiGN8HIJhjdBGOb4Ka26Lq2eJKUSx841CRDV9AxjY0mnTR8KkAxSWQMimFfR0YB0fAbSMgefRMJ9SV3IxOpkF1RiakhUDgc39yD9HFg0x4LK7@Fh9@q2bqzI2GuoizrhjBsQddBKhUWeIQXMJ33mEa3T4oCsUvzssCBMiCYoKWki8D/gvfYenxAXx6vJykBS0iz63vILoBJCnlYchqdxT57ksP7kq3SwntLsx6/oNeE2fJ7tZG0sDze9WglJUZ34rZL/YgCFin6DkTYgsA@2GApb9V5o0/3Vhn5epU7Be6t8g1SVrmxfbmQNh5SeNrJSuZ/Ulraqc/SUwTS26AG2EePEh541aH4HEn6C3vs@v1v//p/p3//27/4W/p3f/O3/99//p8w/J/w5/8EnYUOrwH@/C/w59/jz/@CP3@DP3@5lYnAR45dv/vr/wC3/@N/pH/3L/7CSvo3f@fyR9cFQQpGbXL@1b/Enz/Bn//L5Y@tAf/qzyxAzOLyv1A7qpUHoP78v9A01IalrAv767@naZcPFAyPzXn31hh/9HpfFbAmwz0JPb5Ot375oY5kD3l9LijXvmM3dz7sAO9W4TqHZ2luxh6oM5a7FUppnuOH6NpsR6kG6j88qjCqERwAv837oPTYqwNuaP1/Tx/Tbh/CQDR5fCZtyXC7/Xa7XZtUhPW5GMAOT7yyi8Kwd40JmLcU8DexBJZGEM0WYpGyFo/Y9K3iWb3OBOJyOEsyPayXsutycoPRQ9tHHsL/xtRFpsVpyHr8hBw9StleuuxWhTvi5lW3QS2vY8Bk3DjJb2clEcJEgy6BbGt6I2HxhlDB/7q4Tc/Zw6ZQK74aMPjpgYo53pZI64rStMv1DViktA3vRY0rsgtv4WsD3IeOI4/Utrv@PmDX7e2ti9qKCyEP6X0PKWGrUZbIWCexu0nhraTwVhLgbJVJZE0sHH6FA5k4UC56Xz@gsCuidrNtmAtHjtMPiAbYgtZCoF@Up8Yw/bZoIpF3hd3bwreKZB/T9jh5UIjMOaNd3jcZoMzdPOnXfbm/6NAbmLcdtT8nUnsnZqe33i9pJ8/WoCDUo15Tad1zbGpfz@1W@JWi2Uffd1YUDv0TKwp8Z0Xx2Lcret2tmHen@Pfp@22x44iJtYTfFGYN/IOdCQqnxr8G1tuII8RYJ0GPF0yejG3y9OYq7dlzXCbEM85jzjtnZOpbDz@jEVNVTcFaHvisqWByqKgFbx2Ive9Yevv86YGi6oKx/dyMZPkgK258JotXBwrMan583FqyT2vF3UHrCdndeWU9s9laaM46YxuLtgiFmufTk6RI5tMTKJ@y6N0QEG@DPDqGuik8nBtCW/k9a9W2pnlUPCbC9H67TKLvWtluJH7sqWl2ohsqydBg0PGCDMYXPeT4MR4zT0iCTSRPsaBG2jM9XiTiUJ2oA0FR8Xk0zP2q@NKmbESI0zSCi5/m/DS/hZFtRHt4P@e1s1796qz0VdjDedf5w7sF7BDDT@uvaYyU1fdU9/RudVY2p77mr8e3uY1v8@v4ipJumK9xJpG42oPXX1d1xLMpAQA3aES@jYbffkz0DTo7qKyj8RhaK8N3o9gXDB6mP8Q0A6AZGzwoAn/413cG3K0Rb79H/693oJO98L3dR5TZ5hLkzaSAuh8x0QzyjLzCCx4AL3lR9rytbs3a@e@syzZ0iIXnp11EcCnoXwwDU9MExVhvsDoFf4Pn0W3hDd8TX4a0lbgHJ33mp8fh97so/9QXZG4p9D02pH@rXKfFDYHrE3n1fQ1HQUeEnmqdPewJ@dkdVYw8B0KAjt9hGc4/83rfZysLRFpzD9mMIxiW3qcfWbh7LZpxETRt7YGoOkjQA/L8NXnqXVtqS@vZMdl6P4EtR635x@rJKj5S902CAB2s0@dZ/6Za79fEZ8OzbtJ3zAhr2OBuk/HxEKdEfEDjbR/@OhJ9u6VklWGdKe308o528l6PS1/r8S2ucHjS0kq@jyW/xXTfzXNbrGYVthFhuV83hbwpOcfJMs97tku0Yr7aY6ryRiZgHPaYqrwzqzztEajrnETSmXjMZdrSL7yUBMESXGdwbcMVCwQb9MliKKdtqNc6S14kZcJpW1qLHXPPoy66RUXv9j7iFhTlhHEh92VdJ/9unfybOvmdOtcjYLfKLSCK36nS7gXsnq91gSyI5jvSGZPQcofL18Q2fBSV03Hv9Ytbch9Lfto9cx@DQHYL7uOCB4Syu@8@zpOA4T5uksDYfXwFgc3Ycv/iPnaGBQLocEsCnzHeFuF4z7uPcx7vC0XeSuPUG3Qfr/sUYD5Zt4QiL9byas/e9VfXq6qC4LeUSj@NHGPARcVm3T/6yTcE/wTUPtQEEj@m6fARAUYDZGfS2JoxrHpg2giS11549k0fx87SlL2@sVlDgXRfemtRBblkSuSR@8C9K4wsxDCVLD7CFRBEuXm8HyOafWOZfQsdu3bgUNLJu/UT6gWJPtD3kPR7AN5exJE3@Z3@2i3C6sDvwxMzv4fnG3Sc6ghG6Azg3YMWEvVn91cahX29i4vd@9s99HaNADsx4IBYvUSK3ZLpoMOhbkoq01Rtl0lIKu72Sdt58GMPSuTeV9mIVLBH5jvJJNpuGQqG7cHv/VpztvIhajsiCBPvQ4/WKFvPC0QWY9JG1m1pqtbgAxS2ZE6fPFwrINvm7SCBs8SNn8wV701DTl6rSiK5dsUkZA7i4w5TzrRq3@zL4EMQv858dXKCCg44YgFbOde1WPJV/RX6u2rp745C7RDhVQX7FOv9U@lb9fqrs@wrzOVNtW87EBP9dN67Vzla17AhOVgHW5r513jtjYqP555bSr5V6br0V9q@Q7a1TfANur22LayyUEvQZ7uRY1yYHYffJ9RbjUSeBR2lJYg12eVYDV9jumna13G1Gr6vizEF52i4/OoO1nc7eLvzsDzSAP0Vya1Rjq9mIfsU67GNa@pbOxfWroOKXmLro2u2IkHcE/@1tYsWRNSeGvlatdyFSTeRSHjfbkXgqIW8m3mc@uo2wdpsCfvxcAHydjf0nRiquvnxQXG9dSkjEaAMcGTfxmI/e4x7bVm2Jc9fjV3IZ8FuUdQua7wZBtyOVEJVh8MpW7LpagJBBNNzxNmFOOot0NtPrDXcNULuwA2dpycyfT09oXPO05M9i2HXrLeR/nBgv9shvPWKtoNdb6Z3XnyJCwDTifWCMHsBzn421/JDOcCX8a1fm7nONVVMyXF2wPUh3KJae0Z4IqzXeoefE2O9ag841ROOogkbjuHTY1YuhMaFT@Jaadfz0VJ08Nw3Q1MV@118Y@t9jeQUOsNZeiVoT5U5R9xArFrIQ29bGFkOWc6@GHm9Fjkj0XqXGadYS8gObfy0MAiSHZ9wCkyOsaRZZ8@sXT8ML8lEECY@WkDjnixM8BVXwLt7VpMrEvTKsCgNBsBIjH3epOXgcoNvvQqoYiC3eRVpm7yozD6Ny/YJI8fV2evAQE7PzkPxBh2OgzaV8gNlN18gLLrJ0Pjge4g4aREo@CbgkrCCSf9W3o@epXf3yjofL5b30fOEPfuLNVNA78jA8soWncnnl@2laXvTksiBrZ1L53wHyj6PI032KYPoo6Z5XAcu59QLDFpuE5zMO4@Le/CggmPqg0IED3qA0bzlWwMKroJKG9le865dUhX6BzoSJm/BgfqIlkqqhTKsnb2d0iENsiKylnefLWBcP/RdP@BmIvXhAGWhxWuY32FlDJNzuTa8TH@0i7M2VHAoW0PAuYlt3UTA1Piwp@KPHpcPSvG5vK6dkgDe3v34YEnet1lBKHr/wNz0452imslkbias3jjPDDLDTKML99lQ2dcZRQsMU7iQ@5l8qbc8VxM3MzEcuuleZ3sRXz3RX2jSxSR3oRUoKdqd@O4ii9RFdBXLRXIZPnQrnpfFaCJ3K94aQkYWUsxsNL7uCw2tx@qGdFWtVBsrpti6bg@uR@JdpzNKKE1Ka9xlB9cL4TrZUWbtVqpkXAvtXNUcV0fmlF3WEp14a64Y2fZNdni5LM3Hi1Jc7Uqx3LWQaIvaxZxfxjT@okXdzW6G8ebFcpxiJ/1lJmf0uwmfj@nmsoPkBd@/Ey@buav@QI/1YuNmiovMJpeithxeXSjP5VGuOeN92qhYis8opV6azYVoZ9yTL5S7Rrvdy2fr8zFr3Gn9UbRTmZq9pB6PRKYZYTiKxkpTU0@Ws5mrhJnPlNpF@bZt3i3byTplXpg3idYln5J9s5rJR6b5FmOE2otL6ao5j1@Eb9QL5VIujerj8@l5Xdam43xUqt1MovrgtthTw@GL6@bsolum9Ohlp5tsjMLJPL/gmauYqk4iN6lqWa8sptnnmtDJ8c2s0IuHsrHbAjuq1JZ8bVZuNDp1rdOaJIwrVr4rhkZU7ZZvZrLjYnmSZG@qy1LyvNSc5nKlxawXFgdqZtrvRCq38Xm5KpQ610zkgpuaFZ@Uq8nM6PLSWLZbV6XbqnEHw7pyKUXF5SLbzuricz5nVBplpqqPh83oSOlr7YSUU/nLeilqlsaZi3nnLlXKjgWx3hur45uO3JmaUn7EFKllbnzd6gnzorSac4VouX3NjAoN3kxkBpEmMxLF3liuGavBeXk1aE57g36qdh7KC89X/Ww71ihobKVoRKvKkureZEVp1bgW2XE9dVG66xUyUkWJ5eqCVj@/mC3C4a4k1uexFbu4HRWj0oKPhsq17G3Fd30ZbvjKvmy2rkZqAyqcL553BrErn1oUVkxZ5J4TOZ8@nUYX@Sm@J63cUmR9EpNDyeKNb5gw9E6qUpn3jNJtI9fh5VXyrjIex@8a1O2sZKh6OHlZzKSY@jikn3OjaukuISnF6Dx7LhdSpc6qlTQL5amcvCgP8pcNPX8z4W9ThUFzuRwPkpdCvTzOUEIy32iMeoN2b9FtGvVlqBLlRz1f4bxQfR7AOG43i@HLVjY@mDYi7au8MqvfFH0r9bZT1nLVMVuoJ6fxm0RkQs0Wl8lM01QkLX9eScWvp1K5kMkPWjlWFYTbZ/6KHXPNm2UoaST06@LttWb4zJueGu0Ns5HldaXLtO8MI3YhUXeLTryUGev8VX9hXhqJGyWs1q5D7LVYbcmxWUd67tbVUWbCXLVuV0xvviou6iZvNsdqrJ@Ijc8XxrO@utKvqGR3xMmtak4tj/j4VVdaJZgYq9x0c2KF716GQ5nW4KIiFC9mg1VLmIRHF8/TC57jjXqm2zuX47OF5hMjyVmZuql2bgeJ5@dQT6h2U1Jm3GrUS2b4hmOm3WY59lzuGkaRb5WkbFRSpvls93w8yd0tuRtjsZrexHuyuKzr4VCBWlS7lTY/UgdG0bjjR6vb4p1SmYbjt7WRmDD7Y3YiseW2GEpUtYYv76vL573BMt6eCjMeNEPtuqSx2cxoVKNq7CQxyy5ThqmcG1fVXu4yI2Uy5WT4WgsnLsa584tFX2q32tWLPqdG73q5SLzWG4TC/Wy1MKhHJ4NEvZqIlnPUTW953WD7@aTEDjk5N7pcRrVUOZyNM@154@J6dDNUqnIu01mI2Qh/o84THU5UWsIqnmAqId9omLpUMqFoPU61zLzZKhfnEZ9yVaqE68slf9vjphFOfO4aPr67Gq5qbYFT5WH5ucHetKflnDQateNZ/iZUyzZD05Ux57RynUrl6wqbLy9mxfmw2QkZWv5CS/YW1X6uXhd6Wj@iib1aZiGGZp3O3fV1q6ZMbq8nF41Er7bqc6NY2xQb8drCpJ5B5WnPyq1ib5EXDXHUmD0r54vpbZuJts4n5VZ/5hul7rqziHRbC5Wr2bbITUvXg4TZqi60yqUsyswkXBsw1LxVX61MIaMWqvNKdyG2V6uMlDWe2cUVw5XPS/lb05cqFDP52k2T0@Va7bycz3CTeWVevk34hFWz0o9J4@c7qq4ocli/a8qJbChihFux/CrHj85D0/Ps5ObyJsVqbOuiXalcsUOZn/CJbi0f71T4TiZzebW8FLl2va7Vr1o3VM2n3N7d3TC1G7mcEsulxo0aK830SqeT4OZq5poLlaKT3ry8yM4r02lnkrr0dU2Bi6grQWAbc7nMCBfAO0lKmM7quWrdWIafV6PnwSyv3rZTGe08nsktxf5MmK1CmfzMxxjFxbwfl7Rk@Ka7OBe7fGUwuGpkhxFtpt3EczHqMiVWlHYvN6yklsLVRbldnJpCs9@LSj4jpI1urjMto8UvpXM@Ppy1jK4Mg0/UYjfZXMqQ7/LJK13yhZJ8luI7Fa7OlIex2@plX53nFpX2Mg8mR5IV66GYulTa0@RYubgysled56tkctDqXYyh4unwbshLLV@23xOuRblK3d1etceF@rTNjK5vK4l668KXXEX082deHZ5zqeXNqhYKCWJqMCtNFxGtzCfPk1c1Xr5cVBstURjEm@Fr@VxZUXklMQxlRHY@myuMbxnLJgsDMduqKnq@xV8kBLXOMcyic2fWOrfJq/B56DrUnMxDYaMyZ0JiV5GW3Wq3G@5T2ZlxpXWa7KzguzAz3eaowZ/LTLXTKK3UZbkQNlqZak68ms6XWnkp6ZE7vnyek@u8xIJaEosPbvTWeJWd9aiOuCjnssnEXfgCOMgw5NS8G@UE3tAGixFTrkwv5MVoOm7rvsmCafjuuotYatgeGgxfLt9US/OCHlMvjZFCxeN8@KKjawmj8TxZlnJmfthuydFcqj3o1S66TOVGvEpd55p3CSFWZ0rPQqrTjIf4cqzDM2xDncxMmJH4wZgqL0N9nZcFnUtMa8@xwnTq6y9nU9On3SXOr5KdwTjHznjOF8n01Gdu0b6UQ1I1IQyMWmc@uy12QENU2rOWQhXvWlrkSroQmxftWmXM1jONlclkUx3@Njro6qyoiLNGxIxdloRBghfzhbvxKH9Rei6FuuJzaM7K@vV1pHjBUgnRlzXVvsy0r7VrZRXmhEy3lqzM@6vcZFgVhYtSOK93G/F@84qTCzCNSs/lkNYunpfv@j15yIiqUms2QiHqLh4udG4bz@ysf11f3aiLC31wmanLkVuxpKj12zabv9aZaiJbvM6NGne5ZTJe1@WecDNI3igT33lE5bmMUo5TCWEmZNsdpiVIETaxWPW4scCwd53xOHnBrOLGiskoxnyUHKxSvfMJ27mrquc3yzFzPlnc1bO37FTwsWyd16hrc1WPnZ93fFfL81ZpILdKIs9wk@XIuMhOhct57zqe8SW10I2v0G8PF@X6QOsUmESvl2SbkUgnaj7360vjukq18@WLSCK/NBdiYTytLpIXWibeXC5a19Ho@G60qCWb8UZswc7UcSGrFQcxRr01Esri5mJQzAoFsSIalVWPn1Dx1bRaKiYLvpjAdevdu5BYYJ6bfdkcDsSbq9tIM87wsYtafX53l88wk4Q4KpTkc5gT51xlsWyOuuPedc2ISJRa6/pK8VV81by7rvaVeueyMuzNB4lEXb9oj1LTVVdrSA2ftmqVeup5vj6R86tbYLh4IxUbteRCqyPd5huhGmXGO5k56OBstiwtB0wpFroSldDlYnKeup104uPuuJ2bNbqL8SjeTMTUqbBKmJ3n2FRoJbqXkybD97rzoS98TqnN1fK2cB3Vy9W5VjbrqnAVSobLd@PWpDBt@Sa5q2LPzHVCWi/cKc@nvlwMtIJkpZ0KV3tXo2xpfH5tXFyHU9RNUVpOk6Pz@LmvDpPJdGTUkm05LM@YDiO35zNhPAlx1TzX1he9VrHcr/bDSUbzSYm5eRV/vuzW7zhTiyoMZSzj/TnnuyiABpGXurGmr21qoQnYIqHbWeRKGUTChnLbbPJmTk2MW5GUEC3qbUVtL9RROyxdnyfGc166GlFZYdWPyq1Gp19drOb91Dja55qzVqZ4q3QiOUUbLgydjaeuwm3uuT7RIzVTq5dbfFa5nnCcOPct5Gy@ojdnVH9QzfQ7xeepOGtHa5loZnnbD0Wnd7MRq6xuC93wqN7LDMV5oxNdNeaRbP@cVRoTSZvoYSZ001YK4@SidSFcUZergrAcJq@z9Xa0dTVKjSPyYNysh5bjmiTyd3fGlC11B@Vrtl@KtbPXqfGFaGSERCslXo6YRbVXu4vn@kI0RPmGpQkTzpX5yGXh1mde8nLsWVqxVXOVEpVltSX1moNZRiv3R61pNXvBZNnw7HxRm0QuGkxkymUnyfyV3tVlSijEMotWrRI3hncZsx1V6@FZUrurS4PbcL8@5PhJKJ4EGVzp9@6WrUwjOy93qxdNI6MMVoJPn18p56ViMatQF2Kn@mw8c6o4zURbtXL3@vk6ow9uYj3TKLGLZ4FZLpXaZY7nl91MyRhX25dNpZQITfrZSuJ62C8rLbUuRa4oPpUY3yYYpclfTkNCtJ6JFp/b5/xzaRZvqGPF5G8Kd6xZbYCwK8VaNa07n6xyw5C4iEQLt0Zt0NfuYLSOVlR4etHo9hviSFnMG5dm@yoyabLj9lwexxVO80ULqVqNYwcRNMJit6oyUeWrgXnbrM6udIYZruJTQTsXriSqHNYGmVIjfhnmzs@7@VSLnTyXhXCyEp1m5uFao@JTYoKWLw0mcig3boyEawlMhk68ProMNatSa3A3zd2mlk1q1e2JKeWyM1evcuN5fjwb3bQWETCvbtplw2g2bs1@aRbuXSbkXm3Yv8kXc9d8juOMRE3JFWpjbdruTeYX0Rg1KkZuR5XEpTSIjxMlYdm9mmqp@uWqlBteRH1d5TJpdjlTfq7Jo@dqzzR7zwmp3by@ZDrZBK@EnpcJ83bYYQzqIjkpnEeFxKo0ZBMtZTKbTvu1hqKWlvXrCpA5EY7cnPeYjNa5rpvt/oXA3160QNO/VIVS8/ZSa57fXvSnfYWSI8C@OUa/Oi8bxdv8@I6dlxrLnsT6xrWreS2WiImpnm8Wm1SH03ws1klMLquzYl7T44sKSP1BfVkvC41qhWInlW5h7LsUWTapV1btWbSREW7jvcpcnEdj@cxCGSaTrdDi@vKcv072tNJ80rpkB9fM/C41NiZci2tkeFWsUdlnLbLML8xCKFa4il/cXguj@LxfmIZLmXmzU4qbqarY6USf5435WKgWWfFmMZuH68XatalEY4v29d34CnohRvGDxXUhIVSiQj8kre5yelHtKS0uE2IumfC81b72qQPluSr4xvVwMaLFC6FFnQPL@C47vezHe62R3DnPXqSGVD/KF3w3Rrx0F3@@fa5I@u3Il5iAyEmKjdl1BVSSntm6iS6uxVSXXbVzyQ7XK67YwhWTiV5cTFOlcPiynCp3KaMZmwC3PM/Dt5d5OXxdb99Ep758Nb/oD5t3rUZuXkneddlJvdOcXaIxFmFCc7E2arSW1eKiJQnxwrhRELOUr3Q9N2opTWzk2wWdqffFYnQ0vjgvngvTK366KCi@0KDUWs6epxMheVmROUFXig1zmOEj3eQ4suBLWub5qk0tL7jCJZtLtpP6WOIvR9WWMTJmHU2UMtHn2MJnNkZ16SqWb9zcKqPWsFrV@VwlnDCE/Lg5id@1RoveTCj0LynRTM14eXFejZtKdlmUbluV68t@M7Tk68nLalFfhHpM8bkZmplMK9ms3wx6VV0qj2Di9HVbqpqUQaSYQ/Wa4rRhKTRvZ676yYGROw8ly5eLWkuq@kLXhcYoHzZmuo8ZTmrh/EotXEbEeWLQuL6ahPTcrD/0XdUTzN0oq86rVMzsRzqcMU41RLbbbTNaobEyjEqy1fNdXcuM0AjfJbIXK/amF9H602E32Z2cz5673cpzr928gO689QnxZuWZGlxfXRgJMcWz/VY2V86oMy10qU8aYnRSVrutcFf0dRf50vw5fBUqjko9tlodrlZZ/lLvKMn8pFfJcctRK9mmIoVaqH8XEbTLVv65WxxOR3yuvOAjt@qF4buNVhfTcz2ZiLPR1IwzIu3JpO1LZmTJl4gMl8NwtjCL55m@3uhQhZov11FVGAWNuzhXZYxovyqbRitx0yykGrli7qJ8VbgVy6lmibu99XWvS7lC5iZ@eTUcR6@6rJFlspXhqBmmRuXcuM@YZnIqNaWiUTjX84vh3fh6Mu3NE7Oy0V0pV9xUGkxYkdPGnbKSiGeu28@xWihSqDCFu5WshBOxRYrq82L/kpEb49tOUipcMF15CAZ0Hvh/fFuZ6ryoG8NUB1peWSmJXKs2aOsX8rAOGMq9qcaLk5Q0HgqRO6rBNJPFREe@EvlatzFJdHvS7c1lJCFOF2C/dvOrKzHPQK@3us3hNHQbL4DqGo0@lzrDyfWs2jYasXz7plyPUu3nRl5kS4VyuX1n9tlqLTQozsxWInlRYPlJdlwtLLO9bGle5FudC9/IF77p87NiOyMX2n3OWCzvQqmQnhFHVHwUr2TFPGvOY21Rj@Yuh7UIJ5fURe0yqU0a9ctw9rJwLapjPZS9zjifeHuZmkix5UDMZM7bpW5uQGWuc/lRuC0afEPxzUsELFuUuT/86qNCBF1XCBg1U6U@TV5SaR9zcfKVgyfIyRP4ePvOuRPo7LN9kIBoP18NuEA9flcLnxA@tiohe5tBPB4atxZPXu8tBljnOAFywXM86CNyJLS4sxHq0jHzGo2PkvI1BMiOJ9lBwX0w8njyD8YxfAEHv1MkkIk8UechtPF@EzdCETzng8VztR5PtrY8Pew2NoggdBmniEBPv@sHPFXhR8hItoALtaJ337Z@6GQnPyBnaAo5acQVCLpIVvtUDCxptwirNzF@fTYDRQ5kcTbWvvLCC45hk6F4ipzvQSt@0z@5Tz36j/i0ixZMiVMmxlSf98cDdTgTaZnWRr0Fv1w903QsSkegrvCPtA/rZONphhxomIDfJJ0K2Ucykc8ncjArnktFjoTDc3XdNB1YH@v0kfaSgB9/jl0nb7iUPpo4XGgd8jG5jz@mlXToZHKvPJ4oPp/X9KVNH@vzYMSPrPdEm9qeiPfmI3lqnzmiK86j9XgcNPr@qiJdVxV@qLoNmrxCbvuZE3L6ljOAJpy2PZ5mAm@q@naMiPzETXYG4tso3CXmXuWUVAfOXGoCbt2tTyWQ8d2a@PNhGo@evE3HFn74gEdonNi@E9sN@EJp054s8cfUB0JP3ALHx@mPj@1DYXg81Qw30DBOsiItXGjJ8GDyiZPKq9rSzixZIE9OW063ijzz4N6q1/89kA5UD3jyCV/eoQOYBWKRdwechqLJ1qjXwgrDZUFZ74PiOT7eEzzlhP7opDkn/iA88g05d@fJpCVySg9cTmkblJyBQXvtEydI7L2ED70RV4Izt5X0YTSdaGT/OWjha1MEX/f1pHGSvs4ZNKb4EnIPzSIxJAdp7AEMvOAZaDPOFLa7xukLdHwjD19he7C8OjleHhDmOV1fomzEhw@wvL5K8nyw3ifnoU3Vcqy00LDzkmZ47a4GwuFxo27NfUwTP7gTiCJboidbqSNIxba@kzyB5AlnDt9JHmLZU@O9ZB2S8S1z7yRLkGw9E7k/XYV0a6f/HQATvTyBXZ9M9cnkJNljHeiBR4G8WALbQ/t8DmHXLEBbHWP1x25@2j4ahf5o9Y7FbDvsBeOTsJUFgCztsQcP3m@4haTiaaweiy@26rRoQn@hv1mZ7RwJJH4iNYHYxfq9Rzvl01sIwPgDUUq/TXcqt3p73dAd/gnCtDPA3gZiRehffvkaZjYj7vIf@@hwn9VD6Ie71UKLWptyrNdwbfrVyrSyM@3PYx8dsy3dHB@JTTucQRneiBBrbG3GtSgpfagDCv64HY0uT1760ybm3nikj9fSY0NHa1h8m47hN9yDHlFkRPrp3ibIfz9VOeR7yMnBjNzbCAs8J4w7eUNOYw0d2IU@A@g1NV/xGb/DM/Yo/bWN/b7WHAB@ZFAT2pxYgpYH1fDMRnAPepzVr9sywSrs0H1sxePbxaTdwqR3CrPO03uCAsxTwAFnNkeMO3OipAStZ1JBzofCUT9xMbdAXjZkcoTV99Dpn2FwIeHsKXuKL1zZFUn0HtK8AV@3G@l19nrIvWqeJen3N@7eeqjZ/cmNONJv@Ylw3SeYJY/pEL0@uOmEfvm2HPrHUebLpvt29B3D876scDrd4cTvYcGXdwj9TSbbbUL4kd6h@JS8zln75pREDiHcPyltXOufnBjH7dIa2@9qYIjVyW464mwV6CSAorydy2/rXGcb0WmfvvhkOsqNf6OFkTeIE64Alf2E2hbnaM4VyeS9Hbs@OopQZDsFn2RHDVN3MJNER7cFNdjJF@SfsJstIiM9YUwPVLXvcRQmW2EgJTgndACQ3zrOaq1WWerlpnqozlZ66YF9yocz755AzEc7iswrEIHKp82biMTRgAybExw2W/qNZJDX8JF0nI2gKufpA3RWtKQPffw6HqHXKtCHvZkciY9nkpGTK205T2biHfHgynEKOoZid1im9akL49cdgTBnYGhvzrckffCyZ5XBOsPTPt3yy7bpIp1IQdSJ153ueEF6T9bYnJ66sJo1w7/84eAjMzV0picpjKDMaHxrN3VAC4r19pljfENwIImOwviCX1uaEL9s4oQIbAI9hbUFFWHusV8CjKeIuryUdSYdcVpkKTy4l/iNy8KsD1q/dWKLphoL8rsEYyEUnGqmSlLsisjZdfQv0i@b81RD5Cki22Kw0Tkl5WxgPPh8gRW7tHwlA6ylILF4KrF3q4h7zEkEruvB5cL@Q0Rtf9L7R8oIChw/RCSQ936xzCnoLsLJL5ThdD2etYakwIdXIChbp0xoxHcUqyDaibEk99B8vGcxYMUQF1fke9tOoYhDMKbIqqohk6MrKOY/BQJYhP/QvMkXGo2g/fYBy2MdvdwtP2Z8RJAcWGe/wNt240VvdTwu0OqUD9hYLNuqL70pnMhfQiOs1iYTDoU5ktOiFZ5HaLUgwJK7N81Yw3stcEIS8riTfWcgLUP2qR4a6FFIu002z1a2gJPNAd4ixYdvUoPjeTwIoiJMVMA4J8gyIG3R4sOGHBhEijj1@9b1G/dY5@MaeSs98CY9sJMetNItpDZQQX6ob4COt4FcB182cC@0awPmf1NXmoZGl6rkdKmgqm/hffI1WCMIRpq0AT5bd6XFleuE052EwFbKT3t630r5uJNnzeDr9Hsr3ebvsN3zayx3YD/v1o9Xyu4ggZzBYD@y@IpLg4okWy@V36QQCUvjsUpWduxvwnbWoLQXRGxxEgAxgS/axmF7lt6U4mMdiUPGjOvs9LMraC9JffK8RsN6a86bgbVnjGxRidTpI4RbkJkE6iHJH7eKIGUio9HOyD1zMi/tzMutYhHqo1Mt5ZwUujvAoWmvh3ga3bp/wR9nsO8i58Ad7E/8YGG@sBpvPWmxSyAidD@69pNpV5qY@lSwIu1GfWUW2dS9fF3ifiFRVdEC5YfkfepOnYL1PIioTpX@x7Wc2BYUjqR4Q/d1ik3pDQDrsO97XYiJL9T/Dw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)

### Explanation

This is another addition from [this polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95207).

Braincopter is another image-based brainfuck derivative.

Image should be converted from XPM to PNG with ImageMagick (see [Piet answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139477)).

Braincopter IP follows this path:

[image: Braincopter path]

Corresponding brainfuck code (with R/L rotations) (first and last 2 instructions are irrelevant):

```
+>++++++++++++++++++++RR+++++++++++++++++++LL++++++++++.+.-.L++
```

`.` is white.
Yellow is `+` in both ImageFuck and Braincopter, so they share many of yellow pixels. `+` at (x=2,y=0) is non-yellow to match number of yellow pixels
needed by ImageFuck.

Piet code is delimited by black walls. Piet commands are in slightly different order than in previous answers. First push is magenta because
blue interferes with ImageFuck (blue == `<` in ImageFuck).

`Q`s on the third line create new token for Incident.

Comment: I was just working on a Braincopter answer :).  Interesting to see the differences in our approaches.

Comment: I moved Piet out of the way because it simplifies thinking about polyglot for me.

Answer (score 6):

## 123. [Mycelium](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mycelium), 4540 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoO\4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #0C8302",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #58007B",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002439 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4650 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaUnhpT7c0qY6FhRpJegQHaY1XR3o3IQ2h5xJCwbPaYJBq1NTm5q0Ku7PFaELE3UkBTDjRFIGAGUKuqYLJkmO0i1F5ia9PvcqIbZbmqZDskHnBfmXyS8mzauTCaf0DQCM0/lqtlDOvMqfoK9V3RAQCy8YhopxSXpREPhXgCn6mtMltZypnO@kWIyp6Wp/yiPd5lCAdKyqKMmCQfFA1Rmt2ewNYoA@oHWB61tglKjqNGahJ2OZlmhe0@iezA2DPC1LAFsMJWkBWUOvIP2ANtSJsE2AQSuC0KcNTeAlUeJJqbSwMAXFkFTFCNISP6bnkizTfUGGDBtSeD8go6fGVpRVcJDqqxQNH157Rfj67lAAGEVwKi9owBusvIqMBE44PJjrnKYBkcDABhBuShMQBcl0G7TAGRKKGmQxBKVP@KathVClOWW7lvRM4mgO6J3qBLch6CZUL0jw0kNBFwAlt5YFz1yXTGABsjVD1wROp5u6IHh3RXKnSChMxRJMrEiQNNvpqbtQLbqh@awcQU4zqQM90ry5pDg6mKYPn07gm3a5TqhCJU9/OXzAsCWE0MSa7uG8dPo3tME8PAjwXbA9ZqC/UICVAq7INKNqJsMFNCAwYAKBDIdBDAVm4aAmbxVMn75qiy2hsqD60Bp0SaHbflIzfqrr2Ms2TOXGUGlZVQbAT6isPlWQHwodD0ET8Cr0Ez8tzIBrqmK1kTonHG4OJWg0A5uE6wGDOB55b2kKwlDQFSB7Nkedcg1VnhI4yGmYKIDAFciKGEsi3aZFTpIxC6QjKotqXTCmsol5pkofWx6UgdAP0g4ZvNpHoIk6g@I4QEoioA9NtnoeIQqAoSFUUlVM@t2//nf9wQDwZHhe1fu2uLbpvsoTncYRYkFb0CiwqsLJhCyA82PpVnYoYMbJUp8zsXhlaRdBiCClztWp3KdVKFCfS9C1htwMuqMoCrwpWEJuKUI/PeHGlr6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodoD/noJV4gTogMhOYTE0xSQe0Au02mJ88n449nz4@CECcN@g9OmSYwQkIXPCIRMGd@2uS085sGhTKMkzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkKUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhKPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA8wQNEhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK7/dp1Df0KIwp2VOGUy5AVpCCmTheF7QTFtfQU0MEzTS62GHRAbsMTRoDKnDz6/LJmOJPbpulYG63mo9e0TkUMnY5lBABp1Kc7YtR/clHbSTvHxdOgDMXhXu@hlBdgj42fUOCY4hAEImLAR@aoJyA0GeDyV@CLKL1CmWerTGotfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aCSGPfsxTAWZdRSS8S6KALboWzwwxiKqs50I0vjbEV/HzBmTPYjVNYkwHmzFBhkuCLJnMw2spwZabjDYOKYS6Vlrc27NT2AwdHXopiAsQ9PUjGPQ7ZI5nPaC0KxMU1@WzKqCLcuY@lIyVSvck9Ue6FIDOhPjlMDw0560eFUjErdm@MigZmA0iQadhtH2eQoi4nGLBmg5Ep9D4K0kF9G2BIX16wJAAhQETnlEg@jPImiAxlLhPa4gkfsg9BCXn3ZhL3N5IYC51nzJqRNUGXSHDOZonWV1UDMiqBZbURM9ze0dntYKm9hibndwpEqK54v748eP7mP3Gajjjx8/QegUQ58w5IPQJxIKkBDCBTFEcvhJCFPvSQ6Me3S/3DuYF95HbLYFDiUrSfNw98fHkUc/d8/a1zBevaCXQA0BdAAvgMftTacx6PW6zuZQ0WBPtGpftzjbJ9JQF5QBJSw0VTfpSjVfeKplmhdpFzM1dEaWeowCg@HTBLobTDhce/LDzMHJDsG6qppp0mAYT6CLAGTPmShTnUIHhcmCNJHMEpmiyAqK9qbRnNQclGshKG1PSERdnazVi0EJ/FClXYcRFxrSO5M8HHPt1CimTu053lZ8AuMnOEUL8tSA5@mAat2uI23AJALivC0IMyhq4PMhJJnHrSNtyBRBiZO5oN6zyN8zNbSB4wjcV3uCvIhHA4IsBs3FKog9MR6lrAsd6L8HsScvtVjty0CZ0K0CC/FVAudMMJugy8tgutNlySCz6G2OU2vZe6BcVt@I7Gpp1yYlvDGp9tuBrm0sRE6grcYqaqJN6AmMntgOCpi@vs0pSsaQ/OyAvqHobQrJbUx6IvnZA3Bs2xZgqOBEF1lyidMkNG9UFSbFcwI2URXVIgVYJSkcUyeXIAxJ@@jZ1fw7xPQEcQpTJ6YnKRj@BlgglSSQYq8nvQcKfEHSneseMH3a28c2EK7hG@OA3mG8OdVNWejb1//2x31ogLfNM@SWYPLz43XgCfiGTRUQ320tOyvekJ/9LUtgRlNZ4ggbSOhbKHkOp2WcvA7sR43ajg4EhpwOjbt0GheEE39g5PqKnFmU64I87QvOdX8hhMW7JoiVW5EmpEZwRXuKDFHvZH9lQFn5cVqryyrXJ1is5QZJ2LS21S7CghtA5ZgtjQTK6jvodOwcerO@ADaCObV@cUnhW@0qafj9Wn@1IUMxrscKMBnjetI7XEQi4u/JtdVdcEwPiDI3toJPGNxfVasyujQYgC1jX98DAysTJgIaxwvMnFzeVTHK1NCspsDQV/DpsvX7HoizrLkOvAcI1ZTJz68ROyIIPPQNJBWX9AJbLJJeMVXmeku0e4a/Xn6wQDJ4gnpJ8z5fKILj6HoOuFk81LT38@MwTfKnUvtzW@uMBAGviqIgfKvPwrgjTTg5EO5vBd9VwY6duAntAR1xMw4sSJkzQEBMm83CDJqF/HxNaHEo4acyp29CXxHZDTnOVP@92eImjybxqizZkuncvKcLX5vuGzS4gkx@Nlnx7i1/@2At4zAdWIf2d2iVN3HG9o4cfYd6siZLOB3dEoyg@h7veHWO33d771CdCdbv/iFrtZeq71A/AZlIBszA3mbv898SV1z6Iz/7uTjeS5XJy3vjj@lrVdVhtmzQ4WAIDRyFrFfDgC3L1oSwWaq@L9OGJKsG3SC/X@MFWOWGYf3ul@ZttkmcEuCHVh9bh/dn20sUGd7oDPl9p3E5eaDK8eSA4eDnXQmY6iJqefv6vRpuraFY9psaam3uqAprX99V7WP4/5ZwkJVIHef8W8GvWFH71Jk9V3y/gjAjwFW3/ZUrhpIkZ5CxplLvNYDOD@fc0rn@I0aP97jrjB7akhjLYM1hhlQSAqZuGdD/mNKiXy@t/3066g3axLcqsdW4Y1kAjU1@3zQpHQ6xvzIHGwp9v8YS5akwFfZqkGpvJIDYfE13fD9RIbsah/ZiAgPMw83JNdTKngp@F9U4nuPdVxUOJ0vQyb9pzexVNRpY2BpOnWsQqGHgbcaBMtV2GneLd/WpUv8654aa07PV/g6RmPJrNVLy2zbTjhluCOS7X4Ec47Y6THjVCdgQyne0v42UrNNYvzuIScwG80jCJSD9q3iP6fXiINivYI9Aq0pjI4DrSN@neMLvzdQJcCoFczFFMJf4@x639ynSnqrKv6Z1QJ/2JTTTwPjEXfpvtdIx3VhOemC58ZuVy@9oAWeaCNzCKfG7DVsDlOZ34oy8XXj7yii1tQy3t@RzVT47PftGo9ex77LBZDDxVUBnuYtxAu90QYIsFYx8j/mjOTYtWaTEhU1rKXPjTXDwSr1oS2CM1A8Y/FCYCOT2KwY91x9NDefyLtBCxe@e5CBDliX3tqkkmN/ga8NUFcH4KhCpl7PAubec0oQbCMVvys5mCQE38Hhd2gnuX0w4toSdh2zfUAzWxE5VxsLScK77zd8lD004nXwNm7XoTTwa1pteht92xYA4Sbc33o21d8tBSeF1gWyBObss9AFuzE0nMKMzVT1IEziPh/P5vF7KyoSTgoECYA4U8S/ATUfLdcGgYapmElhJpO/v6cMvi@PQMftCp2nXsYt@fLSwku2vwkIjjgF1K@v9IfeYPnQHAu5D94NyTIfcBFSQwUbbC8rtwIkSuVh0bqpOK9yE7HNi2KnpibWZClMn9FcYckpfFugWKB0yoVR1a0vQ2ndu4hrif/37vu3GMRCgkhPJgDF5oKDrkToRhur8k1WuXXpG0zh0A0Ec8yEukmHpgVyGNuaSCd2MeG/AzK5VbCbtzWDbKQpuaih5W1RYjYr6Dl0UTKvRLGr6qmBJhV3wOpdTKZg7TycKPZf65tAIwjxI4QWy2bzeoYAQgimmrqJU@ekS3RdwDaePhJFOLqvqmGylICX/9e@tLXBIlFCEMOwUTzxgtkqkUXGRfWeeV6dAtYNkJeiqDeJBJnO8OcXhEWRasOK9ND/kyN48SGLA2ZnGYqzd6VymQQcKtBs9uHAL7UQSPYeZ@nn7PvSY/g09YYT/9seM94vNN9cPgQRruPy0A3LygnK1nRyC5E2qm3YdLlx2tdBXiLjGrIXK9ufzYJg0l7PTPCFuRkTuhDnZaSbuBAqOnOi/oxjQP@DWS1BbnSZ96JlayjrQMOkYurmBIuQgZDkmEY8N3DXFLIcL@hd6iLIS4Gk2FoI7iyEybtRP0llnBT6yvUnC5IXelCwZzsLBcCRNqnP4lIaBDEO60FfRb@b@p4f5I2M4XHl4WPwQCi@AbaoO4D8y2HMKlfyXw@BZ6JdfDJgVuVwv7hNrtwi69@GXWqlWaDQzzVYD2Phi1fKgqOoTbqMiUAg0GearQ1UmnkjAD10SjG@rjQ9Eb1AfbECPhz7k6FOYJ9CgoT6sFYvNVlfAdWgFrTSiSXaybfJ92M34KucHknWT@jpZlGyibCWE97bs1IjM2OLhNraVpd8RI2wC6NlT0M4OC0D8vuxReoQpLjoNbAkAWwj4utrru33s2U0l8FazfSIR0HZ2jbbB9nNsF9WH17j2o7JYuAF7B8pmoPNBRlqE2Eyx8lgc2Muhl38mtmgw1P1zsYXg@jZbEGw/lMOGt2yBzNS3qrZFSTFTKrfqhT0V@0adPnzYg@UNkg/b1bGh9gAB@daHWtfHGcI3frWFBRhbMMSIRHlYHnpWZ1JtbzBH58KQOrR8Rjh5M2oY9EwypJ4skO4l4pgng9pEfUP2RAzUmzSq6CCdkQ0Yo/p9ULq9pYk6GwarINkFt7bCAwrtOgDGBNcmhJ92UQhrpN96BYFOnsOUif/ZynxI4Ahmg9rjxfggML/71//O8lx8MCH8p3ZYhPC/ssI/Mcigt95XFo1r1iBb2qUabYAhYFV8wi226oRjMY71kjKF1p4AB2eEIQhuEbup7waP574N/IRGAGbioILjCClP0B896I5zzDBoOg1UWQySnVRhAe0AwxDxznmeoicpDH1MPBaPsgwQGZg5CAOShTCgWQi93mOQK2omaemfezx9enpKuwyYOgvp@InFSOaQ@yni@nlN6CHAUpaVdU9DHsiyyQFpZ3Y2zyHnY72YFbWHm3XTjydgQFntAmOwhwQAxIvRis0PFwzyqs0qaHRFWJhkvFo61iOYbgrxyhAsf2IHUQAQWbjR4fG17G626NBxYUuag9vN4OogWAPBjl37ROf@J/rBfFAebb9XGgTmP@wRJAXCf7bHGXYtPZm3bpie106UWBv6c0NRcdO2CNTSnjATjjBs3LvVU1w2KqAX@8UvgBJ6AvQsXpBGqmZkcoXSZbXWeONGSCDdr8HctPvs1PcQCPrvH9cB9yupd5iaLTKN62zRYeU2VZvVD4TYLIG8JnNfaa8pfaf0jrU/@rZskvCmIDb0vYjJlDJQJKuEb7FvUpktwJy1f/OmVI/3y8v94@nZg3Lwpvhf9nlYHwSPULgg9GAQ/2o3vUfnlJxd3yY@1WIEHQeisGvz/MDag8m630S/71y4fkZm42Lo7C@jg2H4jOkLM0aZyjIVfGfnGeoeZKyiiHedRZhDL@gah1QWSd0UyFNvdu@2qaHturx9nMd2ylozqWpNvImnM6fAnEuXeAvaIAramp4Tt1yYoJXMzZwO5om4RkGmrksyTQNVsd4N60tk15TTHW@xdUpDmEiBpkMPKo6NwyAoMnSEG0LdZKl3wqXvF/Taf@prvoRBQ5Ml04NOfIsgTn@hNh4vVoA9lQX0ATxNPdoOh7TjF@gjroW1KfCrpmr0ZskhLzihOsw66fwUkIMYCPTldAJwIrnUBRwlBLqiBiAz8NHtEHEPpXjsOgQn/RiUHhwKi740gJHG4/WDSvqBZTdOiZzX535Q3KCHLVad4zbfNmN@lSPlFse4ey4oKX1h4UEP9@NH5A7Eu@edmdvreiMDxJvTdu3sv3brdJQFZ9q9duMS@UohpFJrRbDbd1Kp4NCg0L8NJk5QYsPUyxCEMdQjTjiN9kyJX6xBB2ly63nwKH7D1L104AzHszmt0D4fmXLBhSQEaZJTJCFJxmUtDz764WHS0M4Yayh9vKwkjb5ng8FHCJNCvPQhrpbkwNzAdQYvBcYlZDkmaGEAhr9jpGgOk0ukyLoekmIpXOrQAWpvMunIgyHpgMALUmv67Ed6ow02PdDiaip1bLfGrjpM0SAWp3s0BqDdo@YcixP4azspAddQiQFUDibREiiUz1eCokB/9YDMTKB30twUhEz3@p2HCf2bR1pICQcWiRe21xMQuvuoS8H9RVbBnjlkTsiM/eQFxv2fH3DgF@2hf8n8ERNkTr54DuX0kgFjzHvmORymWV/kyOc7VI48hwqaIz/@iBP9l0Owdp6CrqBrAUCBQ9l7AvIM1lH6UDk55E49h/10@IjkgFufz/sFMvzGYIJfDrkX5vBHsCb8EKNbvdNzaHixO4SCQfYF6MMecsj4QWa@eFy0a4FPLGDxh5LPhzQED5@QgN8wDw0fGVceGgxZWjixjVxmMHHUyK6tsm6JN883Wgy0o4/XGj1GvFet9e8nB3j7SZc9afvsoz/84YCNw5TpUzziUT@FIx@PDuiDzy7myKW7vjzkZyfue04MB58fa@Na7db74HEf5KouNuqC2vx0Qh8x1AFzFPolwTA///wzWJ/0/VnwLPjovQ@4H@89i7NE4ujEH08e@T/7Wbf/5ICW2RDLej3hsJehHxr0Q4LjjnzR8GflRJIkzej34asO8bkrsMTSKCUf4ONha253LOJu/ISu3J8@fYQ/8g@f9S3@fiQxdjQBefv56KU9zwvq4OzD4ns/T/CtZkmwzbBs@AFnbJH4x88foMqCj3yOjz@TeQztSiRdqvoZgenhAcvGaPUARr6FQPfoxSKAH@qAXywOVpDIHizhj8VP/uDpYEFTB79Jp33f@VmsQ8HgkxOiDn4@/Tn9T/hQBzDPODg7e3x58QXugz8h8kdfwHd6f3oaPDtbnAUez@6pgy/UweKFOgi7QFwejqiD9OK0Tii4z5/ZtDzbk@AyhE8Dj/darVzINAr@8GngIFzM5PzhRit7wMJdbHOLiRG8rRcy@Wqr6Q9buc5L7UKrBvHG49PZ58@@IDDyc/DsEUhZ/OA786VN06Tvno6C9Nc/T9aFWYfWCdRB/mzRYgKnQG7ZjqmTcgIPcPfghdJ@oQ7uD@49n8KfwiE5NAuxY3Z8rVY3/9UqxEuL0EjVQ8PQkO1D0y5CQiu0DC0XoYlaZfsQFOAvNIGgFBIXoUFICSksu4NHrT5Eq/Hq51eR6/9JVb2uqoBQhczmImQi7pAI10G1eg0oRSh@BH9SKIRULkIz@A/JRNbYn55C3tDDA3VPu34WoO8GWXcw5A7G3W7pMRbXnr@8hOPP92Rkj6Ue74WFZD66aL/76eE@lUq5H08OGOPhgbHUmSscdZ0gyMvL01M@08w8PTG40LE4PfR99gU@wyd95ju1L58O@mfI1ODpxwfK7Zl3Oh38duazuRUiASuus07cviEB@MzeybsbWOwXA4/nPvb45cXr9X54cJ@4rZp4PLQA9qrHxT4swiIddnmJIZuCUYCNoK0Rj3nPzuIxuI8nvQFPiCRbWR5cmqY9uIJkYhwkvgrpdEbXuSUBisJA9ODi9KcH1334MZ1OxUh0LJCK06oeSEW8Lq/3J/b01C4j7IVol3vhUnU3/eVl@8/z5eXUQz5e/PN6MdL@PfN6INkbg7vFF8/i1HPqwTiIwlxfXs4wSOC@QOje4330vrxYcfDr8Z5aOM@8wDuc/f8z/qsGbWi0@@DlAA0IhY7GvJ7eUvBG456kL2X/pT9CBTyuiDsC9XK5Off9/eejyFEiev/p8ejxyHN6FDx6OHvcUc9e9wENsuzIXpo9QL5RB8GTuosNu9woiye4QaHKQlCG2X0kdbIrDO4nz9HrT5JN@Y58n@@PUimr7KOjXz7StBfQQWEu@ByA/NIe@vTsdC1UG5TeM/h@oW0mQ/jlC8iZlQb2iMfeiXh4WIRCBP6klz78csC9nBD09IvLfbIjrgS9x31CtqhcX1yHnH7PPrpeXIdfei9otx2xXmIexKInJ0dRK5xInsAwzR7ZKSFI8VqLmDFIEQyOJx335AClyQ0s90Kl0j1hIMEQp@3wyBeLxZgw/C5@iBfCC@oEt3KsfSNXwGX1HzqZIvgOaMNIUTA16EHDz@lECAZAWeZ0WhXFj1Y8zHHoniCAmSnIMq7U4RQALGG5P4dp50fqAPQMGMCGAJ9JjROmgjCfTufC@pOTjGNuRHtGMIXFz@9/@1f/Ar5/D98/t65//n@kYvj7@9/@z//b7/7mbyHyv8D3/4bvf/79b//tH1tfcv8P8P1/tuL@wf5uwVlfCnD9D7//7V/83e9/@6/@Gr7/q/3969ff3/3lf7L@/1/7D4N/@7u//Af8sW4A11/92e/@7Z8AiX@J4X8JYfi3o//UDm7FWsE/dYKQ79@/Av6z3//23/ydHf6TbZCteMj6pxD/N1vxf0ol6FYNfuql84vm1rVZyOQuqDidrVbyry4xGyhGlwvF5vo2YaU6WWNrFN1Cufz61r5QXXVK8xyKgkBztKUvOZhu4vkPQfqUOmsUmhDdrNLJ5Pp@gfeRMLmvtfC@VKGX5PYWr7Va23C5VArF9CMdS/j9wWAQfvDqJx9yDR7@5ICw75sOB9Q1LoOmWGu/XcIcENKFFO4wgnTPFbLB28NHkKfa@5FwwSgM6tJgCJOvuboGMAwDhrX1MPdm0OtQF9CbJvgcHz7wbaL9DfPyEBXEvhcOp5KxZCoSTvqTqWQ0xsZjMT8b9rOJZCIV8oPlnWTjyViK9SejqUg0Gk35aTYcSyVgnqb0JZFhwIpjXS6aBCSFx6doTvFxJDU4PKMO@oIIk98P9MLT93446DsR9DRJuyLJhxDtYhiY3g85/Whx/5j@4gpH6ASUQLO0y0@5VjRPH4RyyUgojLc9vM0mE5l4BG@fSCp8ciG87eNtIpQsZhN4K@BtLBkKJbJ4K@JtsZgLFYt4W7Vu8YO3S@c2BKhcPNz1ZI4fQ3gA4YEOSgfCCxI/FSCoQhAdZxSTI9h5Yfn2s7KSet@VVF1W@9VeFT5W0mDgpAyq64@VtPdDkkRRBShrAqLi9am6UJ/spKqTZF2rVf7pyfVygi1AFkk8tJf@gvabhzaklQCy6gn5p2CzxD5Nk654wnV8BFfXJ1cEggsPHXLDKORyP7hc3vvU4ydXIuY6hslWwP0j@wmmNCnXsSuRcMEo5QqDIMVcrjgdTrhcd6C5hUHATX9ynbyA3DgCuZYoGgy9YJCGL0x7MF1LW/R4XCkPTVR86sFlDYDWaOL2uN2JsNvtdZ8Ako@0a6sbek@wclA3q2oOgS4gCQhMgb12ogvmVFc8qQBYE3Qg5T15sUj677Zo0sfHhsnpuFxCijymXfGUC6MB5DRllXUW6x0d@9mA/zNljW1xljp4ofr4wEY0RZ@kTnAOBDbX6ZlN3RW9TAx8F1v0nlCHbqTYHdmxQg/I7yFNw2wiEFGj6sHh4SFMu5pnroirGnw6ZewJ1BlDZk4PZye@dDTnI3ORoDM/OyOTmNefaJTSBXQ86OOZNZZVm4whXwa0cQDoTnz/mE8Qyk0DUuoEDR/XgWaZXkuc7dIPFq2nvzkgZi9d@@Lsfk4VspR7fI3Nxh03yGNx94@09zcVSf6SjATOyMKHB5qJhoZ6aaR@SvyU/Om6VW1Vi59Dx8nj5MPD2ykcdWD84lVj7G@Uy5ODY80dibojMEFLH1j1ZRPeg7NwImhwy4NH22PKE02A/NBwT8yfMHsgdnY/852b2YTMYqGk5B/1BwMp/EfXP/9yyDBuN02zh/HfBE6t/1P4yVWtIlzxmMuLnmTGT08/PR3AZD5Fu8IxlGAfQ1tmyrZR5VkcKeRPODLInyBsIgy4de4wXfAeMQzTDoOaT6XiyfgB9QeG@dpGBaSuV@5EQdCN6WTf0l1Gl645XNZU1st3ELiergQdrs7JMc54QOOAgGvTOCJsx9mDxFYUOXBpN25pMOjnhbEUhSGJHMdFi6gTPGiim2Sbmz7C467Qv81LfaE@AK4pbxIXMfg5oagPuJ2Ptx4Hzk//aJhe3P4MeakPHywtAMBBw3xC5JjJjgywJ9QLhezh@n2DxlVVsptpOcVxuGGuapY/sLykrUwG0aLW4Eb82bDcLYKPaNGiAmpzRJMSCeVYOav4DxZYbyoiKcVSuQB56DQtktV5O7dL7@FZCaR6H0WvXTgdgijEguCEUwQcAQEdRHoIbu8EPe94D4H00Symi2SVH6BgqPcTSvy0aGe8x9tHyI7oRV5WDUBsle6xakAfPdnF2nWw6SGVABZi7YhCxgCnD3i/3Xr4hOz9I4xAjtePB1PpUzrsXXt72LigMawzyUhGftK3BIccQmGzmWBjH/3QtCeWN4VnDWfHbBj1Qh2Z/smJ1VTaCXXl4b1fcBX45DeTH3/kf9LuJ48n3knaxKvPN4HxYeyRLJAjMz1Jg3ho99LjiXnv80mP6Yn3yoP3MPSkQwAsWsw2vHbdoOZKGmjBnSLD61/dK4HfKI/@4r3iA5Kn/qO79MrPpUP@BXylNOuX/c9p1q4HlGmmVz7lhDuFLy5I7zjDwFjp4052/WMgy9gjp1f33GMa@CFDRp@vCJUBOo172ed79ELhMiS@zXgi//gj55PPFidyIOBFqJ8in4r3JgQefWm8P/Zwp4tPq/sp5D/2wDUNxcheIB7y2bx@WdMO9J0Aj6023ZBu0bhA8hZA3iSdPrr7dHR3lP74cXW/CEwe/Rb7j0MbaUDiF0j8hmoQw6M7L/2KJWTa7HH9IB3/EDwywLKUfD5gsl/bymlReHQHKRoMeDbVL6gvyVFJzmYHSpjtvWIdbkGevSfTD3Kik0FOsTP76KEIeTMGL0k2uOVaqklgx3Pote2Hia4S4AgEptlHt2Hiw@LTJ8op2natgJJRufRwvgPzAXJyj46TeHIMoOWH/S39uk8NOzp3bZw3SncFGiYCkfhWdyWqiXQ4Q@fvEQTVwJfQy4mlsSyHGlA2RHsADNEeCBdALYJMsvWEDZm2E9HmtBsIcqGeEC1ncTy6wUD9BOpt0/NBhVhkQGfeQ4bkH6WJbgJ5kiBES6ekPAhAV6E@QCWQBqyD9EifgSKjf/yRtm9P0zD1SOBYgGAIN/KxCPSGUij8OygFHEjlCGQU9SEpBGj7gCnoGrZTUPSfVpDtpuqBDL6R3/JWDYZvXX7cVDQs72zkm9ciA9viw4cRmIg2QfBP7GPID2kvfziwh/tjOle9hrlyoX6dacAvG44mN6fDHa/PEXtzIJGGBw31JIU4PfFcnRW6lzzYL2DtgUipfTwlsE9ftsowCa3k/fhAHLD@wJrQw4B6vMYkGOSYESOo6gNmLo0lZvd8UDzRjfhXkaNIA87xbkgOGZzljc/4xmXcwLk4DOb2Uzw7B0xOBMOwz1kKOOdMkrM0iff8BJ3AoRfa5zKRrWtn943s9eL6lZ94EMB0XSKHBw4tBDv5yRE6ppWd9A8Kz1PqcyaHEk2lYOp6TIf8GGCdQNgJRJxA1AnEnEDcCSScQNIJpOwA62BmLcxsOBmJxDfBxCaY3ART62A0tAluMETDm2BkE4xugrFNcFNadF1aPEnw0gcON0nXFXRMY6NJJw0f@VBMEhkDNOzryCgQGn4DCdmjbyKhvORuZCIVsgsqMVUECofjm3vQPg5s2mNR5bfo8FslW3d2JIxVlDW7IQJb0HXQSoUFnvYGQuc9ptHHlaJA7dK8LHBgDAgmWCnpIsi/4D22ng3Rl8frQUpADGl2fQ/ZBZiSQh6WHFxoic@e5PC@ZAtbeC8269kaes2YLY9hm0iLyuNdV2CCMboTt431IypY5Og7EGELAttgQ6W8VWZTn@4tMvL1IncQ7i3yDVEW3ti@XMgbD0GedrKS8Z9gSzvlWXaKQFobzAD7lFoiA68aFB8SSn9hj12//@1f/@/073/7F39L/@5v/vb/@8//E4b/E/78n2Cz0OE1wJ//Bf78e/z5X/Dnb/DnL7cyEfjIset3f/0f4PZ//I/07/7FX1hJ/@bvXP7oGhGkYNQm51/9S/z5E/z5v1z@2Brwr/7MAsQsLv8LtWNaeQDqz/8LTUNpiGWN7K//nqZdPjAwPLbk3Vt9/NHrfYVgzYZ7Enp8nW798kMd2R7y@lyA175jN3c@bADvFnKdw2NXN30PzBnL4Qu1NM/xQ3SutqNUA@0fHk0Y1QgOQN7mfTB67NUBN9T@v6ePabcPYSCaPBuVtnS4XX@73q5NKsL6XAxQh4ej2agw7F1TAtNbCuSbzASWRhCnLWRGyloyYvO3gsc6OwOIy5EsyfSwXsouy8kNkx7aPh0T/jdTXRRaHIasZ4vIKbWU7SfMbhW4o25eNRuU8joGpoybxwu2s5IIYaJBk0C2Nb@RsXhDuOB/jW7Tcna3KVSLrzoMfnpgYo63NdK6oDTtcn0DFjltw3vR4orswlv02gD3oePII7X9nMM@YNft7a2L2ooLoQzpfQ/BsFUpS2Wsk9jdpPBWUngrCWi2cBJdEwuHX9FABg7Ui97Xj3bsqqjdbBvhwp7jtAOSAXNBayHQL8pTY5h@i5po5F1l9xb5Fkr2MW33kweF6Jwz2uV9kwFw7uZJv27L/ahDb2DeNtT@nMjtnZid1nof006erU5BuEe95tK65djUvpbbLfArqNlH33cWFA79EwsKfGdB8di3C3rdrJh3B/37/P222nHUxFrDb5BZHf9gZ4DCofGvQfQ26ggp1knQ44UpT8ae8vTmKu3Zc7IqxDPOE/E7x6nqW8/J4ySmopqCtTzwWVNhyqGiFbx1dvq@NxjYR5UPFFUXjO0ndyTLC1px46NyvDpQYFTz45P5kn2wL@4OWo8/744r65HNtkJz1nHsiNpiFFqeT0@SIplPT2B8yqJ3w0C8DfLomuqm8Bx3CG3l96xN26rmUfFEEdP7bZzE3rWyNSV@7KlqdqIbCsnQMKHjBRkmX/SQ48f4RgLCEqwieY4GLdKe6fEiE4fqRB0IioqPCWLuV@hLG9xIEKdphBY/zflpfosiexLt4f2c18569auz0ldhD@dd5w/vIthhhp/WX/MYOavvKe7p3eKsbE55jV9Pb2Ob3sbX6RUl3TBf00wicbUHr7@u6IhngwEAN2REvk2G334G@A05O6Sso/HEYivDd5PYFwwehj@kNAOgGRs8KIJ8@Nd3BtytCW@/x/@vN6CTvfC9zUeM2cYS9M2kgLYfmaIZ5AAEhRc8AF7you55W9xatPPfWZY90SEzPD/tIopLQQ9n6JiaJijGeoPVQfwNmUe3hTdyT3wZ0lbiHpr0mZ8eh99vovxTX5C5pdD32JD@LbxOjesC1yf66vsqjoqOKD3VOqbaE/KzO6YYeRKFAB2/IzKcf@b1vi9WFoi0lh6yGUcoLL3PP7Jw91o14yJo2toDUXXQoAfk4XpypIG21JbW02uy9SoLW49a44/VkhV8qO@bDAE@WC8qYP2bYr1fU591z7pK3zEirGGDu1XGB1QcjPiIyNs2/HUs@nZNySrDOlPaaeUd6@S9Fpe@1uJbUuHIpGWVfJ9IfkvovlvmtkTNQrZRYblfN4S8wZzjZJnnPdsYrZivtpiqvNEJGIctpirvjCpPexTqOifRdCaeiJq27AsvJUGwBNcZXNtwRYQwB32yBMqpG9q1zpIXSZlw2pbVYsfc82iLbnHRu72PuAVFOWFcyH1Zl8m/Wyb/pkx@p8x1D9gtcguI4neKtFsBm@drTSALovmOdsYknLnD5WtqGz6Kyum49/rFLbmPJT/tnrmPQSG7BfdxwQNK2d13H@dJwHAfN0hg7D6@gsCmb7l/cR873QIBdLglgc8Yb6twvOfdxzmP94UiLzByyg26j9dtCjCfrFvCkRdrebVn7/qr61VVQfBbRqWfRokx4KJite4f/eQbgn8Cap9YA4kf03T4iADjBGRn0NgaMaxyYNgIkjekePYNH8fO0pS9vrFZQ4F0X3prUQWlZEr0kfvAvauMLMIwlSw@whUIRL15vJ8imn0zM/sWOXbpIKGkkXfLJ9wLEnug7yHp9wC8vYgjb/I77bWLwmrA76MTM79H5xtynOIIRegM4N1DFjL1Z/dXKoVtvUuL3frbLfR2jQAbMeCAWK1E0G7pdLDh0DYlhWmqtiskJBV3@6TtPPixOyVK76tsRCvYPfOdZBJt1wwVw3bn936tOlv5kLQdFYSJ96FHq5etxwWiizFpo@u2LFWr8wEJWzqnTx7vFVBs83aQwFnqxk/GiveGISevVSTRXLtqEjIH8YGLKWdapW/2ZfAxjF83fXVyggkONCKCrZzrUiz9qv4K@1217HfHoHaY8KqAfYb1/qH0rXn91VH2FeXypti3DYiJfjrv3WscrUvYsBxmB1uW@ddk7Y2Jj0fkW0a@Vega@ytr32Hbek7wDb69nltYuNBK0Ge7kWNcmB2H32fUW4tEngUdoyWIJdl4rIqvKd1U7eu0WhXf18SYgmM0XH51A@u7DbzdeIiPVEB/xXKrl@NbfMg@xbpv45r61s6FteugopfY@lyerUhQ98R/be2iBRHVp3q@Wil3YdBNJBLet1sR2Gsh72Ycp766TbCetoT9eLwBeREg@k4MVd38@KC43rqUkQgwBjiyb2OJn93HvbYu29Lnr/ou5LNgtzhq4xpvugG3o5XQ1OFwyJZsvprAEMH0HHE2Ese8BX77yWwNd41QOnBD5@mJDF9PT@ic8/Rkj2LYNOttpD8c2K8BCW@9ze9g15vpnXek4gLAdGK9S85egLOfDrb8UA7wvY3rN6yuc00VU3KcHXB9CLeo1p4RngjrtV736MRYb2UESfWEoziFDcfw@TUrF0LjwidxrbTL@WgZOnion6Gpiv3axrH1ak9yxKDhLL0SsqfKnCNuIFYp5LG7LYoshyxnX4y8iY0cp2m99o5TrCVkhzd@WhgEyY5POAVTjrGkWaffrF0/DC/JRAgmPlrA454sTPBtaCC7e1aTryVolWFRGgxAkBj7aFLLwaWJL0gLqGIgt3lrbZu8084@JM32CSNnEdrrwMBOz85j@QYdjoM1lfIDZzdfYCy6ydD46H2IOGkRKPgm4JKwgkn/Vt6PnqV398o6Hy/i@@h5wpb9xRopoHVkEHlli8/k88v20rS9aUn0wNbOpXPCBGWfCJIm@5RB9FHTPK4Dl3PuBgYttwlO5p0H1j14VMIx9UEhigc9wGje8q0BA1dBo41sr3nXLqkK/QMdCZMXJkF5xEolxQIOa2dvBzukQVYk1vLusxWM64e@6wfcTKQ@HKAutGQN8zuijGFyXNhGlumPNjprQwW7stUFnJvY1k0Ephof9hT80ePyARafy@vawQTw9u7HB0vzvs0KStH7B6bZj3eKaiaTaU5YvX6eGWSGmXoX7rOhsq8zihYYpnAh9zP5Um95riaaMzEcanZvsr2Ir5boLzTpYpK70AqUFO1OfHeRReoiuorlIrkMH7oVz8tiNJG7FW8NISMLKWY2Gt/0hbrWY3VDuqpcV@orpti6aQ9uRuJdpzNKKA1Kq99lBzcL4SbZUWbtVqpk3AjtXMUcV0bmlF1WE514a64Y2XYzO7xclubjRSmudqVY7kZItEXtYs4vYxp/0aLuZs1hvHGxHKfYSX@ZyRn9bsLnY7q57CB5wffvxMtG7qo/0GO92LiR4iKzyaWoLYdXF8pzeZRrzHifNiqW4jNKqZVmcyHaGffkC@Wu3m738tnafMwad1p/FO1cT81eUo9HItOMMBxFY6WpqSfL2cxVwsxnSu2ifNs275btZI0yL8xmonXJp2TfrGrykWm@xRih9uJSumrM4xfhpnqhXMqlUW18Pj2vydp0nI9K1eYkqg9uiz01HL64acwuumVKj152usn6KJzM8wueuYqp6iTSTFXK@vVimn2uCp0c38gKvXgoG7stsKPr6pKvzsr1eqemdVqThHHFynfF0Iiq3vKNTHZcLE@SbLOyLCXPS41pLldazHphcaBmpv1O5Po2Pi9XhFLnholccFPz2iflqjIzurw0lu3WVem2YtxBt76@lKLicpFtZ3XxOZ8zrutlpqKPh43oSOlr7YSUU/nLWilqlsaZi3nnLlXKjgWx1hur42ZH7kxNKT9iitQyN75p9YR5UVrNuUK03L5hRoU6byYyg0iDGYlibyxXjdXgvLwaNKa9QT9VPQ/lheerfrYdqxc09rpoRCvKkuo2s6K0qt@I7LiWuijd9QoZ6VqJ5WqCVju/mC3C4a4k1uaxFbu4HRWj0oKPhsrV7O217@YyXPeVfdlsTY1UB1Q4XzzvDGJXPrUorJiyyD0ncj59Oo0u8lN8pV65pcj6JCaHksWmb5gw9E7q@nreM0q39VyHl1fJu@vxOH5Xp25nJUPVw8nLYibF1MYh/ZwbVUp3CUkpRufZc7mQKnVWraRZKE/l5EV5kL@s6/nmhL9NFQaN5XI8SF4KtfI4QwnJfL0@6g3avUW3YdSWoesoP@r5CueFyvMA@nG7UQxftrLxwbQeaV/llVmtWfSt1NtOWctVxmyhlpzGm4nIhJotLpOZhqlIWv78OhW/mUrlQiY/aOVYVRBun/krdsw1mstQ0kjoN8XbG83wmc2eGu0Ns5HlzXWXad8ZRuxCou4WnXgpM9b5q/7CvDQSTSWsVm9C7I1YacmxWUd67tbUUWbCXLVuV0xvviouaiZvNsZqrJ@Ijc8XxrO@utKvqGR3xMmtSk4tj/j4VVdaJZgYqzS7OfGa716GQ5nW4OJaKF7MBquWMAmPLp6nFzzHG7VMt3cux2cLzSdGkrMy1ax0bgeJ5@dQT6h0U1Jm3KrXSma4yTHTbqMcey53DaPIt0pSNiop03y2ez6e5O6WXNNYrKbNeE8WlzU9HCpQi0r3us2P1IFRNO740eq2eKdcT8Px2@pITJj9MTuR2HJbDCUqWt2X99Xk895gGW9PhRkPlqF2U9LYbGY0qlJVdpKYZZcpw1TOjatKL3eZkTKZcjJ8o4UTF@Pc@cWiL7Vb7cpFn1Ojd71cJF7tDULhfrZSGNSik0GiVklEyzmq2Vve1Nl@PimxQ07OjS6XUS1VDmfjTHtev7gZNYdKRc5lOgsxG@Gb6jzR4USlJaziCeY65BsNU5dKJhStxamWmTdb5eI84lOuStfh2nLJ3/a4aYQTn7uGj@@uhqtqW@BUeVh@rrPN9rSck0ajdjzLN0PVbCM0XRlzTivXqFS@prD58mJWnA8bnZCh5S@0ZG9R6edqNaGn9SOa2KtmFmJo1unc3dy0qsrk9mZyUU/0qqs@N4q1TbEery5M6hlMnvas3Cr2FnnREEf12bNyvpjetplo63xSbvVnvlHqrjuLSLfVULmSbYvctHQzSJitykK7vpRFmZmEqwOGmrdqq5UpZNRCZX7dXYjt1SojZY1ndnHFcOXzUv7W9KUKxUy@2mxwulytnpfzGW4yv56XbxM@YdW47sek8fMdVVMUOazfNeRENhQxwq1YfpXjR@eh6Xl20rxspliNbV20r6@v2KHMT/hEt5qPd675TiZzebW8FLl2rabVrlpNqupTbu/umky1KZdTYrlUb6qx0ky/7nQS3FzN3HChUnTSm5cX2fn1dNqZpC59XVPgIupKENj6XC4zwgXITpISprNarlIzluHn1eh5MMurt@1URjuPZ3JLsT8TZqtQJj/zMUZxMe/HJS0ZbnYX52KXvx4MrurZYUSbac14LkZdpsRrpd3LDa9TS@HqotwuTk2h0e9FJZ8R0kbNm0zLaPFL6ZyPD2ctoytD5xO1WDObSxnyXT55pUu@UJLPUnznmqsx5WHstnLZV@e5xXV7mYcpR5IVa6GYulTa0@RYubgysled56tkctDqXYyh4OnwbshLLV@23xNuRLlC3d1etceF2rTNjG5urxO11oUvuYro58@8OjznUsvmqhoKCWJqMCtNFxGtzCfPk1dVXr5cVOotURjEG@Eb@VxZUXklMQxlRHY@myuMbxnLJgsDMduqKHq@xV8kBLXGMcyic2dWO7fJq/B56CbUmMxDYeN6zoTEriItu5VuN9ynsjPjSus02FnBd2Fmuo1RnT@XmUqnXlqpy3IhbLQylZx4NZ0vtfJS0iN3fPk8J9d4iQWzJBYfNPXWeJWd9aiOuCjnssnEXfgCJMgw5NS8G@UE3tAGixFTvp5eyIvRdNzWfZMFU/fddRex1LA9NBi@XG5WSvOCHlMvjZFCxeN8@KKjawmj/jxZlnJmfthuydFcqj3oVS@6zHVTvErd5Bp3CSFWY0rPQqrTiIf4cqzDM2xdncxMGJH4wZgqL0N9nZcFnUtMq8@xwnTq6y9nU9On3SXOr5KdwTjHznjOF8n01Gdu0b6UQ1IlIQyMamc@uy12wEJU2rOWQhXvWlrkSroQGxft6vWYrWXqK5PJpjr8bXTQ1VlREWf1iBm7LAmDBC/mC3fjUf6i9FwKdcXn0JyV9ZubSPGCpRKiL2uqfZlp32g3yirMCZluNXk9769yk2FFFC5K4bzercf7jStOLsAwKj2XQ1q7eF6@6/fkISOqSrVRD4Wou3i40LmtP7Oz/k1t1VQXF/rgMlOTI7diSVFrt202f6MzlUS2eJMb1e9yy2S8pss9oTlINpWJ7zyi8lxGKcephDATsu0O0xKkCJtYrHrcWGDYu854nLxgVnFjxWQUYz5KDlap3vmE7dxV1PPmcsycTxZ3tewtOxV8LFvjNerGXNVi5@cd39XyvFUayK2SyDPcZDkyLrJT4XLeu4lnfEkt1PQV@u3holwbaJ0Ck@j1kmwjEulEzed@bWncVKh2vnwRSeSX5kIsjKeVRfJCy8Qby0XrJhod340W1WQjXo8t2Jk6LmS14iDGqLdGQlk0LwbFrFAQr0XjetXjJ1R8Na2UismCLyZw3Vr3LiQWmOdGXzaHA7F5dRtpxBk@dlGtze/u8hlmkhBHhZJ8DmPinLteLBuj7rh3UzUiEqVWu75SfBVfNe5uKn2l1rm8Hvbmg0Sipl@0R6npqqvVpbpPW7VKPfU8X5vI@dUtCFy8noqNWnKh1ZFu8/VQlTLjncwcbHA2W5aWA6YUC12JSuhyMTlP3U468XF33M7N6t3FeBRvJGLqVFglzM5zbCq0Et3LSYPhe9350Bc@p9TGanlbuInq5cpcK5s1VbgKJcPlu3FrUpi2fJPcVbFn5johrRfulOdTXy4GVkHyup0KV3pXo2xpfH5jXNyEU1SzKC2nydF5/NxXg8FkOjKqybYclmdMh5Hb85kwnoS4Sp5r64teq1juV/rhJKP5pMTcvIo/X3Zrd5ypRRWGMpbx/pzzXRTAgshL3VjD1za10ATmIqHbWeRKGUTChnLbaPBmTk2MW5GUEC3qbUVtL9RROyzdnCfGc166GlFZYdWPyq16p19ZrOb91Dja5xqzVqZ4q3QiOUUbLgydjaeuwm3uuTbRI1VTq5VbfFa5mXCcOPct5Gz@Wm/MqP6gkul3is9TcdaOVjPRzPK2H4pO72YjVlndFrrhUa2XGYrzeie6qs8j2f45q9QnkjbRw0yo2VYK4@SidSFcUZergrAcJm@ytXa0dTVKjSPyYNyohZbjqiTyd3fGlC11B@Ubtl@KtbM3qfGFaGSERCslXo6YRaVXvYvn@kI0RPmGpQkTzpX5yGXh1mde8nLsWVqxFXOVEpVlpSX1GoNZRiv3R61pJXvBZNnw7HxRnUQu6kxkymUnyfyV3tVlSijEMotW9TpuDO8yZjuq1sKzpHZXkwa34X5tyPGTUDwJOvi637tbtjL17LzcrVw0jIwyWAk@fX6lnJeKxaxCXYidyrPxzKniNBNtVcvdm@ebjD5oxnqmUWIXzwKzXCrVyxzPL7uZkjGutC8bSikRmvSz14mbYb@stNSaFLmi@FRifJtglAZ/OQ0J0VomWnxun/PPpVm8ro4Vk28W7lizUgdlV4q1qlp3PlnlhiFxEYkWbo3qoK/dQW8drajw9KLe7dfFkbKY1y/N9lVk0mDH7bk8jiuc5osWUtUqxw4iOAmL3arKRJWvBuZtozK70hlmuIpPBe1cuJKoclgbZEr1@GWYOz/v5lMtdvJcFsLJ6@g0Mw9X69c@JSZo@dJgIody4/pIuJFgytCJ10aXoUZFag3uprnb1LJBrbo9MaVcdubqVW48z49no2ZrEYHpVbNdNoxG/dbsl2bh3mVC7lWH/Wa@mLvhcxxnJKpKrlAda9N2bzK/iMaoUTFyO7pOXEqD@DhREpbdq6mWql2uSrnhRdTXVS6TZpcz5eeqPHqu9Eyz95yQ2o2bS6aTTfBK6HmZMG@HHcagLpKTwnlUSKxKQzbRUiaz6bRfrStqaVm7uQY2J8KR5nmPyWidm5rZ7l8I/O1FCyz9S1UoNW4vtcb57UV/2lcoOQLim2P0q/OyUbzNj@/Yeam@7Emsb1y9mldjiZiY6vlmsUllOM3HYp3E5LIyK@Y1Pb64Bq0/qC1rZaFeuabYyXW3MPZdiiyb1K9X7Vm0nhFu473ruTiPxvKZhTJMJluhxc3lOX@T7Gml@aR1yQ5umPldamxMuBZXz/CqWKWyz1pkmV@YhVCscBW/uL0RRvF5vzANlzLzRqcUN1MVsdOJPs/r87FQKbJiczGbh2vF6o2pRGOL9s3d@ApaIUbxg8VNISFcR4V@SFrd5fSi2lNaXCbEXDLheat941MHynNF8I1r4WJEixdCixoHM@O77PSyH@@1RnLnPHuRGlL9KF/wNY146S7@fPt8Lem3I19iAionKdZnN9dgkvTMVjO6uBFTXXbVziU7XK@4YgtXTCZ6cTFNlcLhy3Kq3KWMRmwC0vI8D99e5uXwTa3djE59@Up@0R827lr13Pw6eddlJ7VOY3aJk7EIE5qL1VG9tawUFy1JiBfG9YKYpXylm7lRTWliPd8u6EytLxajo/HFefFcmF7x00VB8YUGpdZy9jydCMnLa5kTdKVYN4cZPtJNjiMLvqRlnq/a1PKCK1yyuWQ7qY8l/nJUaRkjY9bRRCkTfY4tfGZ9VJOuYvl681YZtYaVis7nrsMJQ8iPG5P4XWu06M2EQv@SEs3UjJcX55W4qWSXRem2dX1z2W@ElnwteVkp6otQjyk@N0Izk2klG7XmoFfRpfIIBk5ft6WqSRlUijlUbyhOG5ZC83bmqp8cGLnzULJ8uai2pIovdFOoj/JhY6b7mOGkGs6v1MJlRJwnBvWbq0lIz836Q99VLcHcjbLqvELFzH6kwxnjVF1ku902oxXqK8O4TrZ6vqsbmRHq4btE9mLFNnsRrT8ddpPdyfnsudu9fu61GxfQnLc@Id64fqYGN1cXRkJM8Wy/lc2VM@pMC13qk7oYnZTVbivcFX3dRb40fw5fhYqjUo@tVIarVZa/1DtKMj/pXee45aiVbFORQjXUv4sI2mUr/9wtDqcjPlde8JFb9cLw3UYri@m5nkzE2WhqxhmR9mTS9iUzsuRLRIbLYThbmMXzTF@vd6hC1ZfrqCr0gvpdnKswRrRfkU2jlWg2Cql6rpi7KF8VbsVyqlHibm993ZtSrpBpxi@vhuPoVZc1skz2ejhqhKlROTfuM6aZnEoNqWgUzvX8Yng3vplMe/PErGx0V8oVN5UGE1bktHGnrCTimZv2c6waihSumcLdSlbCidgiRfV5sX/JyPXxbScpFS6YrjyECXQe5H98ez3VeVE3hqkO1Px6pSRyreqgrV/IwxpQKPemGi9OUtJ4KETuqDrTSBYTHflK5Kvd@iTR7Um3zctIQpwuYP7aza@uxDwDrd7qNobT0G28AKZrNPpc6gwnN7NK26jH8u1muRal2s/1vMiWCuVy@87ss5VqaFCcma1E8qLA8pPsuFJYZnvZ0rzItzoXvpEv3Ozzs2I7Ixfafc5YLO9CqZCeEUdUfBS/zop51pzH2qIezV0OqxFOLqmL6mVSm9Rrl@HsZeFGVMd6KHuTcT7x9jI1kWLLgZjJnLdL3dyAytzk8qNwWzT4uuKblwhYtihzf/jVR4UIuq4QMGqmSn2avM/UPubi5CsHT5CTJ/Dx9p1zJ9DZZ/sgAdF@vhpogXL8rhY@IXxsFUL2NoN4QDVuLZ683lsMsM5xAuSC53jQR@RQanFnI9SlY@Y1GR8l5WsEkB1PsoOC@2Dk8eQfjGP4Ag1@ByWwiTxR5yG88X6TNsIRPOeDxXO1Hk@2tjw97DY1SCA0GaeIwE@/6wc8VeFHyEi2gAvVonfftn7oZCc/EGdoCjlpxBUIukhW@1QMxLSLwmpNjF@fzUCRA1mcjbWvvHKDY9hkKJ4i53vQit/0T@5Tj/4jPu2iBVPilIkx1ef98UAdzkRaprVRb8EvV880HYvSESgr/CPtwzLZeJohRyom4DdJp0L2kUzk84kcDYvnUpEj4fBkXzdNB9bHOn2kvSTgx59j18kbKaWPJo4UWod8TO7jj2klHTqZ3CuPJ4rP5zV9adPH@jwY8SPrPdGmtifivflIntpnjuhr59F6PJAafX9Vka6pCj9U3QZN3ja4/cwJOX3L6UATTtvuTzOBN1V9O0ZEeeImOx3xbRTuEnOvckqqA2cuNQG37tanEsj4Glb8@TCNR0/epmMNP3zAIzRObN@J7Qp8obRpT5b4Y@oD4SdugePj9MfH9qEwPJ5qhhtoGCdZkRYttGR4MPnESeVVbWlnliyQJ6cup1sozzy4t@r1fw@kA9UDmXzC14foAGaBWOzdAacBNdka9VpUYbgsKOt9UDzHx3uCp5zQH50058QfhEe5IefuPJm0RE7pgcspbYOSMzBor33iBIm9l/ChN@JKcOa2kj6MphON7D8HLXptjuC73J40TtLXOYPGFN9X76FZZIbkEI0tgIEXPANtxpnCdtM4bYGOb@ThK6wP4quRA@6BYJ7T9SXqRnz4APH1VZLng/WyQA9tqpZjpUWGnZdUw2s3NTAODzx1a@5jmvjBnUAU2RI92UodQSrW9Z3kCSRPOHP4TvIQcU@N95J1SMZXCL6TLEGy9Uzk/nQV0q2d/ncATPTyBHF9MtUnk5Nkj3WgBx4F8mIpbA/t8zmMXYsAbTWM1R67@Wn7aBT6o9U6lrDtiBf0TyJWFgCKtMfuPHi/kRaSiufBeiy52CrT4gn9hf5mYbZzJLD4iZQEahfL9x7t4Ke3CID@B6qUfpvuFG619rqiO/IThGFngK0NzIrQv/zyNcpsQdyVP/bRkT6rhdAPd6uGFrc2eKxXjG3a1cq0sjPtz2MfHbOt3RwfiU09nE4Z3qgQq29t@rUoKX0oAxB/3I5Glycv/WkTc2880sdr7bHho9Utvs3H8BvpQY8o0iP9dG8T5L@fqxzKPeTkYETubZQFnhPGnbxhp7GGDuxCnwH0mpuv5IzfkRm7l/7ayn5fbQ6APtKpCW9OLEXLg2l4ZhO4hzzOatdtnWAhO3QfW/H4fjNpF5n0DjLrPL0nQGCeAg04sjlq3BkTJSVoPZMKej4UjvqJi7kF8rJhk6OsvodP/wydCxlnD9lTfOXLrkqi97DmDfi63sivs9dd7lX1LE2/v3L31kPN7k9upJF@K09E6j7BKHlMh@j1wU0n9Mu39dA/jjNfNs23Y@8Ynvd1hdPojiR@jwi@vMPobwrZbhXCj/QOx6fkzd/aN4ckcgjh/kFp41r/5MQ4bpdW337XAkOqTnbTkWYLoZMAhvJ2Lr9tc51tVKd9@uKT6Rg3/o0VRl42T6QCTPYTalud43SuSAbv7dj10VGEI9sp@CQ7Wpi6Q5kkOrYtmMFOviD/hM1sMRn5CX16oKp9j2Mw2QYDweCc0AFAfus4q7VZZZmXm@KhONvopQf2KR/OuHsCMR/tKDKuQAQan7ZsIhFHA9JtTrDbbNk3kkFeBEjScTSCopynD9BZ0dI@9PHreIRem0Af9mZyND6eSUZOrrT1PBmJd9SDK8cp6BiKzWFNrU9dGL9uCIQ5g4n25nxL0gYve1YZrDM87dMtv2xPXaQTKYg28brRHS9I78mamtNTFxazFviXPxx8ZKaGzvQkhRGUGY0veKcOaEGx3n9zjK9/DiTRURjf3mxrE@KXTZwQQUygpbC0oCLMPfYbnvEUUZeXss6kI06LLIUH9xK/cVmY9cHqt05s0VRjQX6XMFkIBaeaqZIUuyBydh39i/TL5jzVEHmKyJ4x2OScEjwbGA8@X2DFLi1fyQBrGUgsnkrs3UJxjzmJwnU9uFzYfkio7U96/0gZQYHjh0gEyt4v1nQKmotI8gtlOE2PZ60hK/DhFQjK1ikTGvEdxSKIdWIsyT1UH@9ZDFgxxMUV5d6ep1DEIRhTZFXVUMjRFRTznwIDLMZ/aDTzhXo9aL//wPJYRy93y48ZHxEkB9bZb2e33XjRWx2PC7Qa5QNWFnFb5aU3yIn@JTzCYm02YVeYIzstXuF5hFYNAiy5e1ONNbzXAicsIY872XcG8jJkn@qhgR2FvNtk82xlCzjZHOAtVnz4Jjc4nseDIK6FiQoU5wRZBqItXnzYsAODyBGnfN@6fOMey3xcE2@lB96kB3bSg1a6RdQGKsgP9Q3Q8TaQ6@DLBu6Fdm3A/G/KStNQ6VKFnC4VVPUtuk@@BmsEYZImbYDP1k1pSeU64XQnIbCV8tOe1rdSPu7kWQv4Ov3eSrflO2y3/JrKHdjPu@XjlbIbSCBnMNiPLL6S0qAiyZ@s5cd1CtGwNB6rZGXH9iZiZ3VKe0HEVicBUBP4FnXstmfpDRYf62gc0mdcZ6efXUF7SeqT5zUZ1nt73nSsPX1ki0ukTB9h3IKMJFAOSf64hYLgREGjnZ575mRe2pmXW2gR6qNTLOWcFLrbwaFqr7t4Gt26f8Efp7PvEufAHexP/GBRvrAqbz1pscsgonQ/uvazaVebmPpUsCLtSn1lFNmUvXyNcb@SqKg4A@WHqCnWZQrW8yCiOlX6H9d6YltROJriDd/XKTanNwCsI77vNSEmvlD/Pw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)

### Explanation

Mycelium is another image-based language.

To make polyglot work in Mycelium I changed two colors:

[image]

Mycelium executes first row of pixels, then terminates by falling of right edge.

The code as seen by Mycelium:

```
x
0  #FFC0FF  R%16 == 15  Undefined Behavior (UB), noop in the actual interpreter
1  #000000  R%16 == 0   noop
2  #58007B  R%16 == 8   push 256 * G + B == 123   (also (65536 * R + 256 * G + B) % 11 == 2 (+) for Braincopter)
3  #FFFF00  R%16 == 15  UB (noop)
   ...
22 #0C8302  R%16 == 12, B%4 == 2  print number    (also (65536 * R + 256 * G + B) % 11 == 8 (R) for Braincopter)
```

I don't use op 9 (push G push B) because of 99.

Previous answer doesn't work in Moorhens, so this answer is based on [the version from chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39607998#39607998).

Comment: @WheatWizard It prints 56 instead of 60.

Comment: Huh it does.  When Chance originally left that comment I ran it and got 60.  Well yours certainly works so all is ok.

Answer (score 6):

## 127. [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/index.html), 4848 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xx 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00@O6O4/m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 20 1 ",
# define _ ,
"z c #0C8302"_"b c #B87A63"_"_ c #0000C0"_"d c #708FB7"_"e c #58007B"_"f c #FFC0FF"_"O c #FFFFFF"_"y c #FFFF00",
"h c #E60001 "_"i c #CAFFFF" _"j c #280000"_"k c  #CA0000"_"l c #E60100"_"m c #CA007F"_"n c #330001 "_"q c #E60000",
"c c black", "g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fheyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fibyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fjbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fkggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"flmnqcccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002366 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4961 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaVpSeKkP97SpjgVFWgk6xIdpWtPVgc5NaHPImbRg8JwmGLQ6NbWpSavi/mwRmi5M1JEUwJwTSRkAmCnomi6YJD1K0y1F5ia9PvcqJfaqQE2HdIPOC/Ivk19MmlcnE07pGwAZp@l8NVsoZ15hSND0taobAuLhBcNQMTJJ04uCwL8CTQEop0tqOVM5f5XEhuhzIJ3TZGFBcz3D1DnelFTF4l1NV/tTHutlDgXIibwQJVkwKB5oPqM1uwWCGKAPaF3g@hYYJao6jVnoyVimJZrXNLonc8MgT8sSwBZDSVpA1tErSD@gDXUibJNm0Iog9GlDE3hJlHhSKi0sTEExgDojSEv8mJ5Lskz3BRkybEjh/YCMnhpbUVbBQaqvUjR8eO0V4eu7QwFgFMGpvKAB17DyKjIZOOHwYK5zmgZEAgMbQLgpTUBWJNNt0AJnSCiNkMUQlD7hm7aWU5XmlO1a0jOJozmgd6oT3IagI/ODBC89FHQBUHJrSfHMdckEFiBbM3RN4HS6qQuCd1dmd4qEwlQswcSKBEmznZ66C9WiG5rPyhHkNJM60CPNm0uKo4Np@vDpBL5pl@uEKlTy9JfDBwxbIgpNrOkezkunf0MbzMODAN8F22MG@gsFWCngikwzqmYyXEADAgMmEMhwGMRQYBYOavJWwfTpq7bYEioLqg@tQZcUuu0nNeOnuo7dcMNUbgyVllVlAPyEyupTBfmh0PEQNAGvQi/y08IMuKYqVhupc8Lh5lCCRjOwSbYE31ImhKGgTkD2bI465RqqPCVwkNMwUQCBK5AVMZZEuk2LnCRjFkhHVBbVumBMZRPzTJU@tjwoC6EfpB0yeLWPQBN1BsVxgJREQB@abPU8QhQAQ0OopKqY9Lt//e/6gwHgyfC8qvdtcW3TfZUnao8jxIIuoVFgVYWTCVkA58fSrexQwIyTpT5nYvHK0i6CEEFKnatTuU@rUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITc0pR@esKNLX0hWZILFZ9wPWhYUgApm1Q7QH/OQSvxAnVAZCYwmZpikg5oBdptMD95Ph17Pn18EIA4b9B7dMgwgxMQuOARiYI799ckp53Z0mSgXEzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkoUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhtPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA@wUtFhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK5/ZsQ5gABKFOS1zymDKDdBUUiALx/OCZtr6CmpimKCRXg87JDJgj6FBY0gdfn5dNhlL7NF1qwzU9Vbr2SMih0rGNpYCMuhUmrPNPbov6aCd5OXr0gFg9qpw188IskPAz653SHAMARAyYSHwUxOUGwjyfCjxQ5BdpE6x1KM1Fr0uHqK2SwcFHxDXRSMx7NmPYSrIrKOQjHdRBLBF3@KBMRZRne1EkMbfjvg6Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNshwQZA9m2lgPTXQcoPBxjGVSM9am3NrfgKDoatDNwVhGZqmZhyDbpfM4bQXhGZlmvqyZFYVbFnG1JeSqVrhnqz2QJca0JkYpwSGn/akxasakbg1w0cGNQOjSTToNIy2z1MQEY9bNEDLkfgcAm8luYi2JSisXxcAEqAgcMojGkR/FkEDNJYK73EFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLTp2gyqA7ZDBH6yyrg5oRQbXYiproaW7v8LRW2MQWc7uDI1VSPF/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75d7BvPA@YrMtcChZSZqHuz8@jjz6uXvWvobx6gW9BGoIoAN4ATxubzqNQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbpJV6r5wlMt07xIu5ipoTOy1GMUGAyfJtDdYMLh2pMfZg5OdgjWVdVMkwbDeAJdBCB7RkWZ6hQ6KEwWpIlklsgURVZQtDeN5qTmoFwLQWl7QiLq6mStXgxK4Icq7TqMuNCQ3pkE4phrp0YxdWpPAbfiExg/welbkKcGPE8HVOt2HWkDJhEQp3RBmEFRA58PIckUbx1pQ6YISpzmBfWeE/mFDb1g/HqOt6XEtzHuS38/E@HNnkmpXWgcS@yrPUFexKMBQRaD5mIVxG4ej1LWhQ7034PYk5darPZloEzos4GF@CqB0ymLwiYMFGWYF9BlySBz@O3mpNaC/UC5rI4X2R0CXJuU8MZe229kuraxECEEQRirqOY2oSewqGI7KGBu/DanKBlD8rMD@oaitykktzHpieRnD8CxbbiAFYSzaGTJJc7B0HZSVZhxzwnYRFVUixRglaRwTJ1cgjDe7aNnd1jZIaYniFOYlzE9ScHwN8ACqSSBFHs96T1Q4AuS7lz3gOnT3j62gXAN31ge9A7jzaluykLfvv63P@5DA7xtniG3hPkEP14HnoBv2FQB8d3WsrPiDfnZ37IEZjSVJY6wgYS@hZLncM7HyevAftSoSulAYMjp0LhLp3FBOPEHhsWvyJlFuS7I077gXPcXQli8a99YuRVpQmoEVzTWyPj3TvZX1pmVH@fMuqxyfYLFWsuQhE1rW@0iLLgBVI7Z0kigCb@DTseIojeLF2CAmFPrF9crvtWukobfr/VXGzIU43qsADM9rie9w0UkIv6eXFvdBQ2GgChzYyv4hMH9VbUqo0uDARhK9vU9MDBhYZahcbzAzMnlXRWjTA3NagoMfQWfLlu/74E4i6rrwHuAUE2Z/PwasSOCwEPfQFJxvTCwxSLpFVNlrrdEo2r46@UHCyTjKKiXNO/zhSI4pK4nmJuVSU17Pz/aACR/KrU/t7WISRDwqigKwrf6LIw70oSTA@H@VvBdFewYoZvQHtARN@PAPJU5AwTEtNkszKBZyM/XhBaHEn4qc/om9BWR3ZDjrCO8NxXd5NEkXpUlWzKdm/d04et5wQYNLk@Tn01WvHvL3z6Y4jhMB9ah/R1a5U2cDr4jR9@hnqyZGM51twQjqL7HO16d4/fd3jtUZ4L1u3/IWu2l6jvUT0AmkgHTu7fZ@/y3xBXXFcnPfi6O91Jl8vLe@GP6WlV1mIobdDgYQgNHIYvhMGDLsjXbbJaq78u0IcmqQTfI79d4ASa/YVi/@6V5m20SpwT4odXH1uH92fYSRYY3OkN@32lcTh6ocjw5YDj4eVcCprqIWt6@fq@GW2solv2mhlqbO6rC2td3VfsY/r8lHGSZU8cFha3gV6yoferMnoi@X0GYEeCS3v7KFUNJkjPIWPO09xpA54dzbulc/xGjx3vcdUYPbUmMZbDmMEMqCQFTtwzof0xp0a@X1v8@HfUGbeJbldhq3LEsgMYmv2@alA6H2F@Zgw2Fvl9jifJUmAp7NUi1NxJAbL6mO76fqJBdjUN7pYIB5uHO5xpqZU8Fv4tqHM/x7qsKh5Ml6OTftGb2qhoNLGwNp841CNQw8DbjQJlqO427xbv6VKl/nXNDzenZan@HSEz5tRop@W2baccMNwTy3a9AjnFPHya86gRsCOU72t9GShaBrN8dxCRmg3kk4fqS/lW8x/R65RHsV7BHoFWlsRHARarvUzzh92bqBDiVgrmYIphL/H2P2/sUaU9V5V/TOqBP@xKaaWB8ogvAt1rpmG4sJz2w3PjNsuh3tIAzTQRu4ZT43YatAUrzO3FG3q7qfWWU2lrj21vyuSqfnZ59o9Hr2HfZYDKY@Cqgs9zFOIF3uiBBlgpGvsf80RyblqyA4qqptU66cVU4eKVetCUwRuoHDH4oTARy@xWDnuuPpoZzeRdooeJ3T3KQIWuee9tUEsxv8LVhqopgfBWI1MtZPd1bTmnCDYTiN2Vns4SAu4O8Lu0E9y8mHFvCzkO2bygGa2KnKmNhaTjX/ebvkocmnE6@im1ft@VxpfKb/TTI7F0x/oYVpwzVoTIUhjpj6Pzm7r0@A0JoWo5JX6mEvS9AnD7W@4KG3/ZWgThJt30TjLUD0EFJ4XWB7BI6G1H0Ae5dTicwLzVVPUgTOI@H8/m8XsrKhFObgQJgDhRxwcB9Wcu7w6BhwmkSWEmk7@/pwy@L49Ax@0Knadexi358tLCSHcLCQiO@E3Ur6/0h95g@dAcC7kP3g3JMh9wEVJDB0twLyu3AiRK5WHRuqk4r3IRsBWPYqemJtd8ME0B06RhySl8W6BaoTjItVnVr19Tamm/iSuh//fu@7ekyEKCSE8kAy2KgoHeWOhGG6vyTVa5dekbTOPSUQRzzIS71YemBXIY25pIJyoI4uMD8tFVsJu39cttvDG5q2H@2qLAaFbU2enGYVqNZ1PRVwRILu@B1LqdSvCpPJwo9l/rm0AjCbE7hBbIfv97EgRCCKaauolj56RLdF3Alqo@EEVUlq@qY7DYhJf/17y0vAUiUUIQw7BRPnIS2SqRR/ZKteZ5Xp0C1g2Ql6KoN4kEmQ9@Z4iAPQi1Y8V6aH3LEfQEkMeBs3mMx1gZ@LtOgAwXajU5uuMt4Iomew0z9vH0fekz/hp4wwn/7Y8b7xeab64dAgjVcftoBOXlBudpODkHyJtVNuw4XLrta6E5FvIfWQmX7RHowTJrL2YyfEE8sInfCnGzGE48LBVUDujgpBvQPuPUS1FanSR96ptaQE2iYdAw9AUGdcxCyfLeIUwtuLGOWwwX9Cz1EWQnwNBsLwZ3FEBl9GSbprLOPENne6mHyQm9KFj5n4WA4kibVOXxKw3CMIV3oq@hadP/TwyIcCjwsEoVHxnCY8/Cw@CEUvgXuqTrk@pHBDlSo5L8cBs9Cv/xiwBTP5Xpxn1hbX9DLD7/USrVCo5lpthrAzRersgdFVZ9wG02BsqDJMPkeqjLx2QK26JJgfFt7rDXI@g7APR76kKNP0ZvT610nrEFtVrsCrkMruAaBMWI79zey78tvCFvpbwFszSRKtK1F6RoRJFtm3Ma2BvU7soXtgt19Cjrb4QjuZu5RhYRHLjoNXAoAl76TR/TbWlot@IlEQDN@m1Ffx7EPBfBqA/EWAJm0Lgvra6Vbldtb@Zd/hhprMK79U2tMcHy1xgjxtRoD4CYbyVHMlMqtemE3E4jTxkG3sADDAxSxSPqW5epnSZdqu5U5mgkGnqHlfMLJG91q0DPJkHqyQORNxJFBBuWC3ZHsfxioXWhUZEE6Ixugyft9UE29pYmaDVR6kOx4W9veAYV2HQCzguuB1k@7KIQ10m/di0BzzWF6xP9sZT4kcASzQe1xh3wQmN/9639nuUA@mBD@UzssQvhfWeGfGGTQWzcui8Y1a5At7VKNNmC4tCo@4RZbdcIRC0dESZkKtDQBDs4IQxDcInZT3w0ez30b@AmNAMxE1YvalpQn6I8e9Os5Zhg0MAaqLAbJrqmwgHYAZU3cfJ6n6JIKAwQTj8WjLANEBmYOwoBkIQxoFkKv9xhkjZpJWvrnHk@fnp7SLgOmyUI6fmIxkjnkfoq4fl4TegiwlGWL3NOQB7JsckDamZ3Nc8j5WC9mxS7nZt304wmYGVa7wEjlIQEA8WK0YvPDBUOharMKGl0RFiZR50vHxgIDRyHuHYLlmOwgCgAiCzd6Tr6W3c12HDopbElzcLsZXB0EayDYsWuf6Nz/RD@YD8qj7UBLg8D8hz2CpED4z/Z41a6lJ/PWn9Pz2hsTa0N/bigqbtAWgVraE2bCEYaNe7d6istGBfRiv/gFUEJPgJ7FC9JI1YxMrlC6rNYab/wRCaT7NZibdp@d@h4CQf/94zrgfiX1DlOzRaZxnS06rNymarPSgRCb5Y7XZO4r7TWl75TesfZC35ZNEt4UxIa@FzGZPgaKZEXwLfZNKrMFmLP2at6U6vF@ebl/PD17UA7eFP/LPlftg@ARCheEHgziqO2m9@ickrPD28TnZ4yg4ywUdm0eRFi7Qln3m@j3vRTXT@NsfBWdvWT0VAyfMX1hxihTWaaC7@wyQ92DjFUUcdOzCHPoBV3jkMoiqZsCeerNTt02NbRdl7cPDtneXWsmVa3pKXGZ5hSYmegSb0EbREFbk1ji3wvTmJK5mfnAbArXI8gEb0kmM6Aq1jtffYnMyjndcTtbpzSEiRRoOvSg4th4HoIiQ4@6IdRNlnonXPp@Qa99pb7mlBg0NFkyPegNuAjiJBFq4/FiBdhTWUBnwtPUo@25SDsOhj7io1ibAr9qqkZvJuZ5wQnVYW5G56eAHMRAoC@nE4ATyaUu4Cgh0BU1AJmBj26HiHsoxWPXITjpx6D04FBY9KUBjDQerx9U0g8su/Fu5Lw@mFC7QQ9brDrHLb1txvwqj8wtjnH3XFBS@sLCg67yx4/IHYh3zzszt9f1RgaIW6jtI9p/7R/qKAvOtHvtxrfylUJIpdaKYLfvpFLBoUGhLxvMK6DEhqmXIQhjqEeccBrtmRIHW4MO0uTW8@BR/Iape@nAGY5nc1qhfT4yI4ELSQjSJKdIQpKMS1gefIbEw6ShnTHWUPp4WUkafc8Gg48QJoV46UNcU8iBuYGzcS8FBidkOSZoYQCGv2OkaA5zL6TIuh6SYilcENABam8y6ciDIemAwAtSa/rsR3qjDTY90OJqKnVst8auOkzRIBanezQGoN2j5hyLE/hrOyQB11CJAVQOppoSKJTPV4KiQH/1gMxMoHfS3BSETPf6nQcX/ZtnY0gJBxaJF7aHExC6@8xMwf1FVsGeOWROyLz25AXG/Z8fcOAX7aF/yfwRE2ROvngO5fSSAWPMe@Y5HKZZX@TI5ztUjjyHCpojP/6I0@GXQ7B2noKuoGsBQIFD2XsC8gzWUfpQOTnkTj2H/XT4iOSAW5/P@wUy/MZggl8OuRfm8EewJvwQo1u903NoeLE7hIJB9gXowx5yyPhBZr54XLSLPHaIxR9KPh/SEDx8QgJ@wzw0fGRceWgwZOZ9Yhu5zGDiqJFdW2XdEm8eo7QYaEcfrzV6jHiqWmvdTw7w9iMze9L22Ud/@MMBG4dJ1Kd4xKN@Ckc@Hh3QB59dzJFLd315yM9O3PecGA4@P9bGtdqt98HjPshVXWzUBbX56YQ@YqgD5ij0S4Jhfv75Z7A@6fuz4Fnw0XsfcD/eexZnicTRiT@ePPJ/9rNu/8kBLbMhlvV6wmEvQz806IcExx35ouHPyokkSZrR78NXHeIDXGCJpVFKPsDHw9bc7ljE3fgJfcI/ffoIf@QfPutb/P1IYuxoAvL289FLe54X1MHZh8X3fp7gW82SYJth2fADztgi8Y@fP0CVBR/5HB9/JvMY2pVIulT1MwLTwwOWjdHqAYx8C4Hu0YtFAD/UAb9YHKwgkT1Ykr8nDLMsZKEOfpNO@77zs1iHgsEnJ0Qd/Hz6c/qf8KEOYKJxcHb2@PLiC9wHf0Lkj76A7/T@9DR4drY4Czye3VMHX6iDxQt1EHaBvDwcUQfpxWmdUHCfP7NpebZnxmUInwYe72tlsH6b/vBp4CBczOT84UYre8DCXWxzi4kRvK0XMvlqC6Br5UKmUTgvtQutGsQbj09nnz/7gsDIz8GzR6Bk8YPvzJc2TZO@ezoK0l/9PO0JWbfUQf5s0WICp0Bs2Y6pk2ICD3D34IXCfqEO7g/uPZ/Cn8IhOTQLsWN2fK1WN//VKsRLi9BI1UPD0JDtY6uGhFZoGVouQhO1yvYhKMBf6HM1Xo0yE4iQQuIiNAgpIYVld7C9/z@pqtdVFRCqkM1chEzEHRLhOqhWrwGZCMWP4E8KhUILIHMRmsF/SCZyxv70FMIaekMPD9Q97fpZgP4bZN3BkDsYd7ulx1hce/7yEo4/35PRPZZ6vBcWkvnoov3up4f7VCrlfjw5YIyHB8ZSaa5w1HWCIC8vT0/5TDPz9MTgYsfi9ND32Rf4DJ/0me/Uvnw66J8hZ4OnHx8ot2fe6XTw25nP5laIBKy4zjpx@4YE4DN7J@9uYLFfFjye@9jjlxev1/vhwX3itmri8dAC2KweF/uwCIt02OUlxmwKRgI2gvZGPOY9O4vH4D6e9AY8IZJsZXlwaZr24AqSyXGQ@Cak0xld55YEKAqD0YOL058eXPfhx3Q6FSPRsUAqTqt6IBXxurzen9jTU7uMsBeiXe6FS9Xd9JeX7T/Pl5dTD/l48c/rxUj798zrgWRvDO4WXzyLU8@pB@MgCnN9eTnDIIH7AqF7j/fR@/JixcGvx3tq4TzzAu9wBeCf8V81aEOj3QcvB2hEKHQ05vX0loI3GvckfSn7L/0RKuBxRdwRqJfLzbnv7z8fRY4S0ftPj0ePR57To@DRw9njjor2ug9okGVH9tLsAfKNOgie1F1s2OVGWTzBpXxVFoIyzPAjqZNdYXA/eY5ef5Jsynfk@3x/lEpZZR8d/fIRug2gg8Jc8DkA@aU99OnZ6VqoNii9Z/D9QttMhvDLF5AzKw1sEo@9WP/wsAhZ3ZE@6aUPvxxwLycEP/3icp/syCvB73GfkN0c1xfXIaffs4@uF9fhl94LGm9HrJfYCLHoyclR1AonkicwVrNHdkoIUrzWYmUMUgSD40nPPTlAcXIDz71Qq3RPGEgwzmk7TPLFYjEmDL@LH@KF8II6wV0Pa4vFFXBZHYhOpgi@A9owUhTMD3rQ8nM6EYJRUJY5nVZF8aMVDxMduicIYGsKsozLdTgPAHNY7s9h7vmROgBFA1awIcBnUuOEqSDMp9O5sP7kJOOYG9GeEcxj8fP73/7Vv4Dv38P3z63rn/8fqRj@/v63//P/9ru/@VuI/C/w/b/h@59//9t/@8fWl9z/A3z/n624f7C/W3DWlwJc/8Pvf/sXf/f73/6rv4bv/2p///r193d/@Z@s///X/sPg3/7uL/8Bf6wbwPVXf/a7f/snQOJfYvhfQhj@7eg/hSDtC1gf31Y6/cthCCwp@uGXTeSf0r8wLGh7mllHAtZ//8sDOnGxFqSD8xcmxEK0Bflnv//tv/k7iN2B/BMn@2ca4l5D2uLgFPSnAPk3O3TakH9KJehWDX7qpfOL5ta1WcjkLqg4na1W8q8uMRsoRpcLxeb6NmGlOlljaxTdQrn8@ta@UF11SvMcypdAc7SlhTmYyOIRFUH6lDprFJoQ3azSyeT6foH3kTC5r7XwvlShl@T2Fq@1WttwuVQKZf8jHUv4/cFgEH7w6icfcg0e/uSAsO8bJQfUNS6wplhrv1vCHBDShRTu8EGXmStkg7WHT0lPtfcj4YJRGNSlwRCmdXN1DWAYBgyW68HzzVDaoS6gi07wUUN8Jt1Eyx5m/CEqiB06HE4lY8lUJJz0J1PJaIyNx2J@NuxnE8lEKuQHmz7JxpOxFOtPRlORaDSa8tNsOJZKwAxQ6Usiw4B5yLpcNAlICo/P4pziQ01qcHhGHfQFEabVH@iFp@/9cNB3IuhpknZFkg8h2sUwLgr3P44W94/pL65whE7Q4RDN0i4/mOI2@BPtp1wrmqcPQrlkJBR2Pbl6eJdNJjLxCNw9kTT45EJw18e7RChZzCbgTsC7WDIUSmThTsS7YjEXKhbhrmrd4Qfuls5dKASlu4Z4W4gDVqDmySXhbS5DYOkn1whvw0ksFBLHcIep9q1sZ2XJ3cTKCRRgKQreRSIO2ud1KaRQHm57MseP8YHdAdwMdFCjLj/MSnnS6BBUIYi@P4rJYRZxKCzfflYkSeq9mzTaSqouq/1qrwofkjQeDJyUQXX9IUnyRHnm33xIkiiqAGXNq1S8PlUX6pOdVHWSrGu1yj89uV5OsPlREOmlx/uFWKQe2pBWAnQUT8g/BTMs9mmadMUTruMjuLo@uSIQXHjokBsGVpf7weXy3qceP7kSMdcxzCED7h/ZTzBTS7mOXYmEi/aeuMIgxTGXK06HEy7XHYxFwiDgpj@5TnTBnOoKHT55QQpW6dAJoYR@9uCV8@Nvz/vFBuudvOAiFZD57Fn5fH74ej8hxWBPgonsPV7CCO49eYGe4HSxdR@hwSAOBmn4whQR07W0VUmPK@WhyUiYenDZhoK1kOBxuxNht9vrPgEkH2nXlmLxnhBCaIthHqfWLqgn1DoFdq1dNU8qAFYXHUgBWRZJ/90WTfr42DA5HZeWSJHHtCuecmE0gJymrLLOYr2jYz8b8H@mLBMgzlIHL1QfH2SJpuiT1AlOF8E2PT2zqbuil4mB72KL3hPq0I0UuyM71voB@T3EseYgEFGj6sHh4SHMUJtnroirGnw6Zey55hlDJpkPZye@dDTnIxO3oDOVPcOZ@ZtPNErpAvow9PGgIMv6T8aQLwPaOAB0J75/zCcI5aYBKXWCBqLrQEOB5uUlrgzQDxatp785INMDuvbF2VOeKmTZ@/gam407bpDHBe8fae9vKpL8JRkJnJFFIpQeGhrqpZH6KfFT8qfrVrVVLX4OHSePkw8Pb@e7n0ETS/UCdWD84lVj7G@Uy5ODY80dibojMKlNH1jVZhPeg7NwImhwy4NH2xXLE02gqME9MRbDLH0gdnY/852b2YRM/KGo5B/1BwMp/EfXP/9yyDBuN02zh/HfBE6t/1P4yVWtMlzxmMuLPmrGT08/PR3QYPPRrnAMJdnH0JZVt22DehZHCvkTjgzyJwibCANunTtMF7xHDMO0wzCApVLxZPyA@gPDfG1zB1LXq52iIOjGdLJvuTOjS9ccLgUr6yVPCFxPV4IOV@fYHmeko3Gow/V8HOu24@zhbyuKnHa1G7c0GHQpwViKwpBEjkmjRdQNHpzSmMQ1gD7Cs8bQc85LfaE@AK4pbxJvFPg5oagP6BaBtx4Hzk//aJhe3DIOeakPH2wNZphBw3xC5JjJjgywJ9QLhezh@n2DxpVosgNsudtx6GSgapa/tLykrUwGUdHWsE085bDcLYKPaNGiAmpzRJMSCeVYOav4DxZYbyoiKcVSuQB56DQtkh0NO7dL7@FBFaR6H0WvXTgdgijEguCEUwQcAQEdRHoIbu8Effp4D4H00Symi2RnBKDAiPETSvy0aGe8x9tHyI7oRV5WDUBsle6xakAfPdnF2nVwBgasBLAQa0cUMxk99AHvt1sPnyC@f/TSXxzPIQ@m0qd0eOPaZOOCxrAOhCMZ@UnfEhxyAojNZoKNffRD055YHiieNZwds2HUC3Vk@icnVlNpJ9SVh/d@wZXzk99MfvyR/0m7nzyeeCdpE68@3wTGibFHskCOzPQkDeKh3UuPJ@a9zyc9pifeKw/ewxAEw@ULJVrMNrx23aDmShpowd01w@tf3SuB3yiP/uK94gOSp/6ju/TKz6VD/gV8pTTrl/3PadauB5Rpplc@5YQ7hS8u4u9498CY6eNOdqIwy9gjp1f33GMa@CFDRp@vCJUBOo172ed79ELhMiS@zXgi//gj55PPFidyIOBFqJ8in4r3JgQefWm8P/Zwp4tPq/sp5D/2wDUNxcheIB7y2bx@WdMO9J0Aj6023ZBu0bhA8hZA3iSdPrr7dHR3lP74cXW/CEwe/Rb7j0MbaUDiF0j8yZb3lOfozku/YglZZvC4fpCOfwgeGWAzS2CZHN35ta2cFoVHd5CiwcBnU/2C@pKcU@VsEKGE2R4/1ski5GwCMrEix2kZ5AhBs4@@j5A3Y/CSZINbTquaBDMUDr3a/bSiKgGOQGCafW4eJj4sPn2inKJtdxQoGZVLD2dyMNMhxybpuOZBzmC0/NS/pV/3qWFH566nHY3SXYGGKU4kvtVdiWoiHc7Q@XsEQTXwJfRyYmksywkJlA3RHgBDtAfCBVCLIJNsPWFDpu1EaC2ngSAX6gnRcqbHoy0M1E@g3jY9H1SIRQZ05j1kSP5RmugmkCcJQrR0SsqDAHQV6gNUAmnAOkiP9BkoMvrHH2n79jQN07YEjgUIhnAjH4tAbyiFwr@DUsCBVI5ARlEfkkKAtg@Ygq5zOwVF/2kF2Z6vHsjgG/ktB9ggcYD1TBXD8vtGvnktMrAtPnwYgaloEwT/xE6G/JD28ocDe7g/pnPV61qrWahfZxrwC1Z8cnM03/H6ELc3p0FpeMpTT1KIoxjP1VmhewmzPw9YfSBSah@PaOzTl60yTK8reT8@MAisP7CWKmBAPV5jEgxyDIsRVPUBM5fGErN7eCsep0d80shRsQHnbD0khwzO8sYbfeOMbuAqAwzm9lNOO6d7TgTDsA@5CjiHfJKDTIlf/gTdy6EX2odike1@Z8eS7I/jcp@feF3o0kAiJzcOLQQ7@cn5RaaVnfQPCg@z6nMmhxJNpWDSfEyH/BhgnUDYCUScQNQJxJxA3AkknEDSCaTsAOtgZi3MbDgZicQ3wcQmmNwEU@tgNLQJbjBEw5tgZBOMboKxTXBTWnRdWjxJ8NIHDjdJ1xV0TGOjSScNnyZRTBIZAzTs68goEBp@AwnZo28iobzkbmQiFbILKjFVBAqH45t70D4ObNpjUeW36PBbJVt3diSMVZQ1yyECW9B10EqFBR61B0LnPabRu5aiQO3SvCxwYAwIJlgp6SLIv@A9tp460ZfHGw9bxJBm1/eQXYCpKeRhyamRlvjsSQ7vS7awhfdisx7bodeM2XJPtom0qDzeGWktjNGduG2sH1HBIkffgQhbENgGu/7MTplNfbq3yMjXi9xBuLfIN0RZeGP7ciFvPAR52slKxn@CLe2UZ9kpAmltMAPsI4KJDLxqUHz8KP2FPXb9/rd//b/Tv//tX/wt/bu/@dv/7z//Txj@T/jzf4LNQofXAH/@F/jz7/Hnf8Gfv8Gfv9zKROAjx67f/fV/gNv/8T/Sv/sXf2El/Zu/c/mja0SQglGbnH/1L/HnT/Dn/3L5Y2vAv/ozCxCzuPwv1I5p5QGoP/8vNA2lIZY1sr/@e5p2@cDA8NiSd2/18cethxUsBGs23JPQ4@t065cf6sj2kNfnArz2Hbu582EDeLeQ6xyeebvpe2DOWE5yqKV5jh@iQ7odpRpo//BowqhGcADyNu@D0WMvD7ih9v89fUy7fQgD0eSpq7Slw@362/V2bVIR1udigDo8mc5GhWHvmhKY3lIg32QmsDSCOG0hM1LWkhGbvxU8U9sZQFyOZEmmh/VSdllObpj00PbRpPC/meqi0OIwZD21RI4IpmzfanarwB1186rZoJTXMTBl3DzHsJ2VRAgTDZoEsq35jYzFG8IF/2t0m5azu02hWnzVYfDTAxNzvK2R1gWlaZfrG7DIaRveixZXZBfeotcGuA8dRx53norYB@y6vb11UVtxIZQhve8hGLYqZamMdRK7mxTeSgpvJQHNFk6ia2Lh8CsayMCBenH3CSAr25aK2s22ES7sOU47IBkwF7QWBP2iPDWG6beoiUbeVXZvkW@hZB/Tdj95UIjOOaNd3jcZAOdunvTrttyPOvQG5m1D7c@J3N6J2Wmt9zHt5NnqFIR71GsurVuOTe1rud0Cv4KaffR9Z0Hh0D@xoMB3FhSPfbug182KeXfQv8/fb6sdR02sNfwGmdXxD3YGKBwa/xpEb6OOkGKdBD1emPJk7ClPb67Snj3H2kI845wYsHOWrb51jgBOYiqqKVjLA581FaYcKlrBWwfX73u7hH1O/EBRdcHYftpJsjzHFTc@b8erAwVGNT@eXCDZpyrjvqf1ZPXuuLIe2WwrNGedhY@oLUah5fn0JCmS@fQExqcsejcMxNsgj@68bgoP0YfQVn7P2rStah4VT1wxvd/GSexdK1tT4seeqmYnuqGQDA0TOl6QYfJFDzl@jK@DICzBKpJnj9Ai7ZkeLzJxqE7UgaCo@Kgh5n6FvrTBjQRxmkZo8dOcn@a3KLIn0R7ez3ntrFe/Oit9FfZw3nX@8C6CHWb4af01j5Gz@p7int4tzsrmlNf49fQ2tultfJ1eUdIN8zXNJBJXe/D664qOeDYYAHBDRuTbZPjtp4vfkLNDyjoaj4u2Mnw3iX3B4GH4Q0ozAJqxwYMiyId/fWfA3Zrw9nv8/3oDOtkL39t8xJhtLEHfTApo@5EpmkHOVlB4wQPgJS/qnrfFrUU7/51l2RMdMsPz0y6iuBT0CoeOqWmCYqw3Wh3E35B5dMh4I/fESyNtJe6hSZ/56XH4/SbKP/UFmVsKfY8N6d/C69S4LnB9oq@@r@Ko6IjSU60zwj0hP7tjipGndwjQ8Tsiw/lnXu/7YmWBSGvpIZtxhMLS@/wjC3evVTMugqatPRBVBw16QB7bJ4claEttaT3xJ1vvEbH1qDX@WC1ZwQchv8kQ4IP1lgjWvynW@zX1Wfesq/QdI8IaNrhbZXyox8GIj9W8bcNfx6Jv15SsMqwzpZ1W3rFO3mtx6WstviUVjkxaVsn3ieS3hO67ZW5L1CxkGxWW@3VDyBvMOU6Wed6zjdGK@WqLqcobnYBx2GKq8s6o8rRHoa5zEk1n4omxacu@8FISBEtwncG1DVdECHPQJ0ugnLqhXesseZGUCadtWS12zD2PtugWF73b@4hbUJQTxoXcl3WZ/Ltl8m/K5HfKXPeA3SK3gCh@p0i7FbB5vtYEsiCa72hnTMKZO1y@prbho6icjnuvX9yS@1jy0@6Z@xgUsltwHxc8oJTdffdxngQM93GDBMbu4ysIbPqW@xf3sdMtEECHWxL4jPG2Csd73n2c83hfKPL2KKfcoPt43aYA88m6JRx5sZZXe/auv7peVRUEv2VU@mmUGAMuKlbr/tFPviH4J6D2WTiQ@DFNh48IME5AdgaNrRHDKgeGjSB5PY1n3/Bx7CxN2esbmzUUSPeltxZVUEqmRB@5D9y7ysgiDFPJ4iNcgUDUm8f7KaLZNzOzb5Fjlw4SShp5t3zCvSCxB/oekn4PwNuLOPImv9NeuyisBvw@OjHze3S@IccpjlCEzgDePWQhU392f6VS2NavzlWxWn@7hd6uEWAjBhwQq5UI2i2dDjYc2qakME3VdoWEpOJun7SdBz92p0TpfZWNaAW7Z76TTKLtmqFi2O783q9VZysfkrajgjDxPvRo9bL1uEB0MSZtdN2WpWp1PiBhS@f0ySPRAopt3g4SOEvd@MlY8d4w5OS1iiSaa1dNQuYgPqAy5Uyr9M2@DD628uumr05OMMGBRkSwlXNdiqVf1V9hv6uW/e4Y1A4TXhWwz7DeP5S@Na@/Osq@olzeFPu2ATHRT@e9e42jdQkblsPsYMsy/5qsvTHx8RUClpFvFbrG/srad9i2nhN8g2@v5xYWLrQS9Nlu5BgXZsfh9xn11iKRZ0HHaAliSTYeq@JrSjdV@zqtVsX3NTGm4BgNl1/dwPpuA283HuIjFdBfsdzq5fgKJbJPse7buKa@tXNh7Tqo6CW2PiVoKxLUPfFfW7toQUT1qZ6vVspdGHQTiYT37VYE9lrIuxnHqa9uE6ynLWE/HglB3sKIvhNDVTc/Piiuty5lJAKMAY7s21jiZ/dxr63LtvT5q74L@SzYLY7auMabbsDtaCU0dTgcsiWbryYwRDA9R5yNxDFvgd9@MlvDXSOUDtzQeXoiw9fTEzrnPD3Zoxg2zXob6Q8H9mtSwluvUjzY9WZ65/W1uAAwnVgv8rMX4Ownqi0/lAN8aeb65bfrXFPFlBxnB1wfwi2qtWeEJ8J6rXdtOjHWKzFBUj3hKE5hwzF83s/KhdC48ElcK@1yPlqGDh4XaGiqYr8zc2y9V5UcXmg4S6@E7Kky54gbiFUKeUxxiyLLIcvZFyOvwSPHjVrvHOQUawnZ4Y2fFgZBsuMTTsGUYyxp1olBa9cPw0syEYKJjxbwuCcLE3wVHcjuntXkawlaZViUBgMQJMY@utVycGni2@kCqhjIbV4o3CYvFLRPWrN9wsgph/Y6MLDTs3OUgUGH42BNpfzA2c0XGItuMjQeVxAiTloECr4JuCSsYNK/lfejZ@ndvbLOx4v4PnqesGWth6IkaB0ZRF7Z4rP9rNTW0rS9aUn0wNbOpXMqB2WfopIm@5RB9FHTPK4Dl3NWCQYttwlO5p2H/D14vMQx9UEhigc9wGje8q0BA1dBo41sr3nXLqkK/QMdCZMXSkF5xEolxQIOa2dvBzukQVYk1vLusxWM64e@6wfcTKQ@HKAutGQN8zuijGFy5tpGlumPNjprQwW7stUFnJvY1k0Ephof9hT80ePyARafy@vawQTw9u7HB0vzvs0KStH7B6bZj3eKaiaTaU5YvX6eGWSGmXoX7rOhsq8zihYYpnAh9zP5Um95riaaMzEcanZvsr2Ir5boLzTpYpK70AqUFO1OfHeRReoiuorlIrkMH7oVz8tiNJG7FW8NISMLKWY2Gt/0hbrWY3VDuqpcV@orpti6aQ9uRuJdpzNKKA1Kq99lBzcL4SbZUWbtVqpk3AjtXMUcV0bmlF1WE514a64Y2XYzO7xclubjRSmudqVY7kZItEXtYs4vYxp/0aLuZs1hvHGxHKfYSX@ZyRn9bsLnY7q57CB5wffvxMtG7qo/0GO92LiR4iKzyaWoLYdXF8pzeZRrzHifNiqW4jNKqZVmcyHaGffkC@Wu3m738tnafMwad1p/FO1cT81eUo9HItOMMBxFY6WpqSfL2cxVwsxnSu2ifNs275btZI0yL8xmonXJp2TfrGrykWm@xRih9uJSumrM4xfhpnqhXMqlUW18Pj2vydp0nI9K1eYkqg9uiz01HL64acwuumVKj152usn6KJzM8wueuYqp6iTSTFXK@vVimn2uCp0c38gKvXgoG7stsKPr6pKvzsr1eqemdVqThHHFynfF0Iiq3vKNTHZcLE@SbLOyLCXPS41pLldazHphcaBmpv1O5Po2Pi9XhFLnholccFPz2iflqjIzurw0lu3WVem2YtxBt76@lKLicpFtZ3XxOZ8zrutlpqKPh43oSOlr7YSUU/nLWilqlsaZi3nnLlXKjgWx1hur42ZH7kxNKT9iitQyN75p9YR5UVrNuUK03L5hRoU6byYyg0iDGYlibyxXjdXgvLwaNKa9QT9VPQ/lheerfrYdqxc09rpoRCvKkuo2s6K0qt@I7LiWuijd9QoZ6VqJ5WqCVju/mC3C4a4k1uaxFbu4HRWj0oKPhsrV7O217@YyXPeVfdlsTY1UB1Q4XzzvDGJXPrUorJiyyD0ncj59Oo0u8lN8n2G5pcj6JCaHksWmb5gw9E7q@nreM0q39VyHl1fJu@vxOH5Xp25nJUPVw8nLYibF1MYh/ZwbVUp3CUkpRufZc7mQKnVWraRZKE/l5EV5kL@s6/nmhL9NFQaN5XI8SF4KtfI4QwnJfL0@6g3avUW3YdSWoesoP@r5CueFyvMA@nG7UQxftrLxwbQeaV/llVmtWfSt1NtOWctVxmyhlpzGm4nIhJotLpOZhqlIWv78OhW/mUrlQiY/aOVYVRBun/krdsw1mstQ0kjoN8XbG83wmc2eGu0Ns5HlzXWXad8ZRuxCou4WnXgpM9b5q/7CvDQSTSWsVm9C7I1YacmxWUd67tbUUWbCXLVuV0xvviouaiZvNsZqrJ@Ijc8XxrO@utKvqGR3xMmtSk4tj/j4VVdaJZgYqzS7OfGa716GQ5nW4OJaKF7MBquWMAmPLp6nFzzHG7VMt3cux2cLzSdGkrMy1ax0bgeJ5@dQT6h0U1Jm3KrXSma4yTHTbqMcey53DaPIt0pSNiop03y2ez6e5O6WXNNYrKbNeE8WlzU9HCpQi0r3us2P1IFRNO740eq2eKdcT8Px2@pITJj9MTuR2HJbDCUqWt2X99Xk895gGW9PhRkPlqF2U9LYbGY0qlJVdpKYZZcpw1TOjatKL3eZkTKZcjJ8o4UTF@Pc@cWiL7Vb7cpFn1Ojd71cJF7tDULhfrZSGNSik0GiVklEyzmq2Vve1Nl@PimxQ07OjS6XUS1VDmfjTHtev7gZNYdKRc5lOgsxG@Gb6jzR4USlJaziCeY65BsNU5dKJhStxamWmTdb5eI84lOuStfh2nLJ3/a4aYQTn7uGj@@uhqtqW@BUeVh@rrPN9rSck0ajdjzLN0PVbCM0XRlzTivXqFS@prD58mJWnA8bnZCh5S@0ZG9R6edqNaGn9SOa2KtmFmJo1unc3dy0qsrk9mZyUU/0qqs@N4q1TbEery5M6hlMnvas3Cr2FnnREEf12bNyvpjetplo63xSbvVnvlHqrjuLSLfVULmSbYvctHQzSJitykK7vpRFmZmEqwOGmrdqq5UpZNRCZX7dXYjt1SojZY1ndnHFcOXzUv7W9KUKxUy@2mxwulytnpfzGW4yv56XbxM@YdW47sek8fMdVVMUOazfNeRENhQxwq1YfpXjR@eh6Xl20rxspliNbV20r6@v2KHMT/hEt5qPd675TiZzebW8FLl2rabVrlpNqupTbu/umky1KZdTYrlUb6qx0ky/7nQS3FzN3HChUnTSm5cX2fn1dNqZpC59XVPgIupKENj6XC4zwgXITpISprNarlIzluHn1eh5MMurt@1URjuPZ3JLsT8TZqtQJj/zMUZxMe/HJS0ZbnYX52KXvx4MrurZYUSbac14LkZdpsRrpd3LDa9TS@HqotwuTk2h0e9FJZ8R0kbNm0zLaPFL6ZyPD2ctoytD5xO1WDObSxnyXT55pUu@UJLPUnznmqsx5WHstnLZV@e5xXV7mYcpR5IVa6GYulTa0@RYubgysled56tkctDqXYyh4OnwbshLLV@23xNuRLlC3d1etceF2rTNjG5urxO11oUvuYro58@8OjznUsvmqhoKCWJqMCtNFxGtzCfPk1dVXr5cVOotURjEG@Eb@VxZUXklMQxlRHY@myuMbxnLJgsDMduqKHq@xV8kBLXGMcyic2dWO7fJq/B56CbUmMxDYeN6zoTEriItu5VuN9ynsjPjSus02FnBd2Fmuo1RnT@XmUqnXlqpy3IhbLQylZx4NZ0vtfJS0iN3fPk8J9d4iQWzJBYfNPXWeJWd9aiOuCjnssnEXfgCJMgw5NS8G@UE3tAGixFTvp5eyIvRdNzWfZMFU/fddRex1LA9NBi@XG5WSvOCHlMvjZFCxeN8@KKjawmj/jxZlnJmfthuydFcqj3oVS@6zHVTvErd5Bp3CSFWY0rPQqrTiIf4cqzDM2xdncxMGJH4wZgqL0N9nZcFnUtMq8@xwnTq6y9nU9On3SXOr5KdwTjHznjOF8n01Gdu0b6UQ1IlIQyMamc@uy12wEJU2rOWQhXvWlrkSroQGxft6vWYrWXqK5PJpjr8bXTQ1VlREWf1iBm7LAmDBC/mC3fjUf6i9FwKdcXn0JyV9ZubSPGCpRKiL2uqfZlp32g3yirMCZluNXk9769yk2FFFC5K4bzercf7jStOLsAwKj2XQ1q7eF6@6/fkISOqSrVRD4Wou3i40LmtP7Oz/k1t1VQXF/rgMlOTI7diSVFrt202f6MzlUS2eJMb1e9yy2S8pss9oTlINpWJ7zyi8lxGKcephDATsu0O0xKkCJtYrHrcWGDYu854nLxgVnFjxWQUYz5KDlap3vmE7dxV1PPmcsycTxZ3tewtOxV8LFvjNerGXNVi5@cd39XyvFUayK2SyDPcZDkyLrJT4XLeu4lnfEkt1PQV@u3holwbaJ0Ck@j1kmwjEulEzed@bWncVKh2vnwRSeSX5kIsjKeVRfJCy8Qby0XrJhod340W1WQjXo8t2Jk6LmS14iDGqLdGQlk0LwbFrFAQr0XjetXjJ1R8Na2UismCLyZw3Vr3LiQWmOdGXzaHA7F5dRtpxBk@dlGtze/u8hlmkhBHhZJ8DmPinLteLBuj7rh3UzUiEqVWu75SfBVfNe5uKn2l1rm8Hvbmg0Sipl@0R6npqqvVpbpPW7VKPfU8X5vI@dUtCFy8noqNWnKh1ZFu8/VQlTLjncwcbHA2W5aWA6YUC12JSuhyMTlP3U468XF33M7N6t3FeBRvJGLqVFglzM5zbCq0Et3LSYPhe9350Bc@p9TGanlbuInq5cpcK5s1VbgKJcPlu3FrUpi2fJPcVbFn5johrRfulOdTXy4GVkHyup0KV3pXo2xpfH5jXNyEU1SzKC2nydF5/NxXg8FkOjKqybYclmdMh5Hb85kwnoS4Sp5r64teq1juV/rhJKP5pMTcvIo/X3Zrd5ypRRWGMpbx/pzzXRTAgshL3VjD1za10ATmIqHbWeRKGUTChnLbaPBmTk2MW5GUEC3qbUVtL9RROyzdnCfGc166GlFZYdWPyq16p19ZrOb91Dja5xqzVqZ4q3QiOUUbLgydjaeuwm3uuTbRI1VTq5VbfFa5mXCcOPct5Gz@Wm/MqP6gkul3is9TcdaOVjPRzPK2H4pO72YjVlndFrrhUa2XGYrzeie6qs8j2f45q9QnkjbRw0yo2VYK4@SidSFcUZergrAcJm@ytXa0dTVKjSPyYNyohZbjqiTyd3fGlC11B@Ubtl@KtbM3qfGFaGSERCslXo6YRaVXvYvn@kI0RPmGpQkTzpX5yGXh1mde8nLsWVqxFXOVEpVlpSX1GoNZRiv3R61pJXvBZNnw7HxRnUQu6kxkymUnyfyV3tVlSijEMotW9TpuDO8yZjuq1sKzpHZXkwa34X5tyPGTUDwJOvi637tbtjL17LzcrVw0jIwyWAk@fX6lnJeKxaxCXYidyrPxzKniNBNtVcvdm@ebjD5oxnqmUWIXzwKzXCrVyxzPL7uZkjGutC8bSikRmvSz14mbYb@stNSaFLmi@FRifJtglAZ/OQ0J0VomWnxun/PPpVm8ro4Vk28W7lizUgdlV4q1qlp3PlnlhiFxEYkWbo3qoK/dQW8drajw9KLe7dfFkbKY1y/N9lVk0mDH7bk8jiuc5osWUtUqxw4iOAmL3arKRJWvBuZtozK70hlmuIpPBe1cuJKoclgbZEr1@GWYOz/v5lMtdvJcFsLJ6@g0Mw9X69c@JSZo@dJgIody4/pIuJFgytCJ10aXoUZFag3uprnb1LJBrbo9MaVcdubqVW48z49no2ZrEYHpVbNdNoxG/dbsl2bh3mVC7lWH/Wa@mLvhcxxnJKpKrlAda9N2bzK/iMaoUTFyO7pOXEqD@DhREpbdq6mWql2uSrnhRdTXVS6TZpcz5eeqPHqu9Eyz95yQ2o2bS6aTTfBK6HmZMG@HHcagLpKTwnlUSKxKQzbRUiaz6bRfrStqaVm7uQY2J8KR5nmPyWidm5rZ7l8I/O1FCyz9S1UoNW4vtcb57UV/2lcoOQLim2P0q/OyUbzNj@/Yeam@7Emsb1y9mldjiZiY6vlmsUllOM3HYp3E5LIyK@Y1Pb64Bq0/qC1rZaFeuabYyXW3MPZdiiyb1K9X7Vm0nhFu473ruTiPxvKZhTJMJluhxc3lOX@T7Gml@aR1yQ5umPldamxMuBZXz/CqWKWyz1pkmV@YhVCscBW/uL0RRvF5vzANlzLzRqcUN1MVsdOJPs/r87FQKbJiczGbh2vF6o2pRGOL9s3d@ApaIUbxg8VNISFcR4V@SFrd5fSi2lNaXCbEXDLheat941MHynNF8I1r4WJEixdCixoHM@O77PSyH@@1RnLnPHuRGlL9KF/wNY146S7@fPt8Lem3I19iAionKdZnN9dgkvTMVjO6uBFTXXbVziU7XK@4YgtXTCZ6cTFNlcLhy3Kq3KWMRmwC0vI8D99e5uXwTa3djE59@Up@0R827lr13Pw6eddlJ7VOY3aJk7EIE5qL1VG9tawUFy1JiBfG9YKYpXylm7lRTWliPd8u6EytLxajo/HFefFcmF7x00VB8YUGpdZy9jydCMnLa5kTdKVYN4cZPtJNjiMLvqRlnq/a1PKCK1yyuWQ7qY8l/nJUaRkjY9bRRCkTfY4tfGZ9VJOuYvl681YZtYaVis7nrsMJQ8iPG5P4XWu06M2EQv@SEs3UjJcX55W4qWSXRem2dX1z2W@ElnwteVkp6otQjyk@N0Izk2klG7XmoFfRpfIIBk5ft6WqSRlUijlUbyhOG5ZC83bmqp8cGLnzULJ8uai2pIovdFOoj/JhY6b7mOGkGs6v1MJlRJwnBvWbq0lIz836Q99VLcHcjbLqvELFzH6kwxnjVF1ku902oxXqK8O4TrZ6vqsbmRHq4btE9mLFNnsRrT8ddpPdyfnsudu9fu61GxfQnLc@Id64fqYGN1cXRkJM8Wy/lc2VM@pMC13qk7oYnZTVbivcFX3dRb40fw5fhYqjUo@tVIarVZa/1DtKMj/pXee45aiVbFORQjXUv4sI2mUr/9wtDqcjPlde8JFb9cLw3UYri@m5nkzE2WhqxhmR9mTS9iUzsuRLRIbLYThbmMXzTF@vd6hC1ZfrqCr0gvpdnKswRrRfkU2jlWg2Cql6rpi7KF8VbsVyqlHibm993ZtSrpBpxi@vhuPoVZc1skz2ejhqhKlROTfuM6aZnEoNqWgUzvX8Yng3vplMe/PErGx0V8oVN5UGE1bktHGnrCTimZv2c6waihSumcLdSlbCidgiRfV5sX/JyPXxbScpFS6YrjyECXQe5H98ez3VeVE3hqkO1Px6pSRyreqgrV/IwxpQKPemGi9OUtJ4KETuqDrTSBYTHflK5Kvd@iTR7Um3zctIQpwuYP7aza@uxDwDrd7qNobT0G28AKZrNPpc6gwnN7NK26jH8u1muRal2s/1vMiWCuVy@87ss5VqaFCcma1E8qLA8pPsuFJYZnvZ0rzItzoXvpEv3Ozzs2I7Ixfafc5YLO9CqZCeEUdUfBS/zop51pzH2qIezV0OqxFOLqmL6mVSm9Rrl@HsZeFGVMd6KHuTcT7x9jI1kWLLgZjJnLdL3dyAytzk8qNwWzT4uuKblwhYtihzf/jVR4UIuq4QMGqmSn2avO/VPubi5CsHT5CTJ/Dx9p1zJ9DZZ/sgAdF@vhpogXL8rhY@IXxsFUL2NoN4qDduLZ683lsMsM5xAuSC53jQR@Qgb3FnI9SlY@Y1GR8l5WsEkB1PsoOC@2Dk8eQfjGP4Ag1@ByWwiTxR5yG88X6TNsIRPOcDD9ILPZ5sbXl62G1qkEBoMk4RgZ9@1w94qsKPkJFsAReqRe@@bf3QyU5@IM7QFHLSiCsQdJGs9qkYiGkXhdWaGL8@m4EiB7I4G2tfeU0Jx7DJUDxFzvegFb/pn9ynHv1HfNpFC6bEKRNjqs/744E6nIm0TGuj3oJfrp5pOhalI1BW@Efah2Wy8TRDTqBMwG@SToXso5nI5xM5TxfPpyKH3eFpyG6aDqyPd/pIe0nAjz/HrpM3UkofTRwptA75mNzHH9NKOnQyuVceTxSfz2v60qaP9Xkw4kfWe6JNbU/Ee/ORPLXPHNHXzqP1eIg3@v6qIl1TFX6oug2avI1x@5kTcgqX04EmnLbdn2YCb6r6doyI8sRNdjri2yjcJeZe5ZRUB85cagJu3a1PJZDxNbX482Eaj568TccafviAR2ic2L4T2xX4QmnTnizxx9QHwk/cAsfH6Y@P7UNheBrl9sMHEidZkRYttGR4MPnESeVVbWlnliyQJ6cup1sozzy4t@r1fw@kA9UDmXzCV67oAGaBWOzdAacBNdka9VpUYbgsKOt9UDzHx3uCp5zQH50058QfhEe5IefuPJm0RE7pgcspbYOSMzBor33iBIm9l/ChN@JKcOa2kj6MphON7D8HLXptjuBb4p40TtLXOYPGFN8h6aFZZIbkEI0tgIEXPAttxpnCdtM4bYGOb@ThK6wP4quRlwIAwTyn60vUjfjwAeLrqyTPB@s1hB7aVC3HSosMOy@phtduamAcng/r1tzHNPGDO4EosiV6spU6glSs6zvJE0iecObwneQh4p4a7yXrkIwvJ3wnWYJk65nI/ekqpFs7/e8AmOjlCeL6ZKpPJifJHutADzwK5MVS2B7a53MYuxYB2moYqz1289P20Sj0R6t1LGHbES/on0SsLAAUaY/defB@Iy0kFY/P9VhysVWmxRP6C/3NwmznSGDxEykJ1C6W7z3awU9vEQD9D1Qp/TbdKdxq7XVFd@QnCMPOAFsbmBWhf/nla5TZgrgrf@yjI31WC6Ef7lYNLW5t8FjvTtu0q5VpZWfan8c@OmZbuzk@Ept6OJ0yvFEhVt/a9GtRUvpQBiD@uB2NLk9e@tMm5t54pI/X2mPDR6tbfJuP4TfSgx5RpEf66d4myH8/VzmUe8jJwYjc2ygLPCeMO3nDTmMNHdiFPgPoNTdfyRm/IzN2L/21lf2@2hwAfaRTE96cWIqWB9PwzCZwD3mc1a7bOsFCdug@tuLxnXDSLjLpHWTWeXpPgMA8BRpwZHPUuDMmSkrQeiYV9HwoHPUTF3ML5GXDJkdZfQ@f/hk6FzLOHrKn@JqcXZVE72HNG/B1vZFfZ6@73KvqWZp@f@XurYea3Z/cSCP9Vp6I1H2CUfKYDtHrg5tO6Jdv66F/HGe@bJpvx94xPO/rCqfRHUn8HhF8eYfR3xSy3SqEH@kdjk/Jm9G1bw5J5BDC/YPSxrX@yYlx3C6tvv2uBYZUneymI80WQicBDOXtXH7b5jrbqE779MUn0zFu/BsrDN9OZ0kFmOwn1LY6x@lckQze27Hro6MIR7ZT8El2tDB1hzJJdGxbMIOdfEH@CZvZYjLyE/r0QFX7Hsdgsg0GgsE5oQOA/NZxVmuzyjIvN8VDcbbRSw/sUz6ccfcEYj7aUWRcgQg0Pm3ZRCKOBqTbnGC32bJvJIO8PJGk42gERTlPH6CzoqV96OPX8Qi9NoE@7M3kaHw8k4ycXGnreTIS76gHV45T0DEUm8OaWp@6MH7dEAhzBhPtzfmWpA1e9qwyWGd42qdbftmeukgnUhBt4nWjO16Q3pM1NaenLixmLfAvfzj4yEwNnelJCiMoMzCqe0vqgBYU651Bx/hi6UASHYXxvdC2NiF@2cQJEcQEWgpLCyrC3GO/OxpPEXV5KetMOuK0yFJ4gC/xG5eFWR@sfuvEFk01FuR3CZOFUHCqmSpJsQsiZ9fRv0i/bM5TDZGniOwZg03OKcGzgfHg8wVW7NLylQywloHE4unE3i0U95iTKFzXg8uF7YeE2v6k94@UERQ4fohEoOz9Yk2noLmIJL9QhtP0eNYasgIfXoGgbJ0yoRHfUSyCWCfGktxD9fGexYAVQ1xcUe7teQpFHIIxRVZVDYUcXUEx/ykwwGL8h0YzX6jXg/brIiyPdfRyt/yY8RFBcmCd/d53240XvdXxuECrUT5gZRG3VV56g5zoX8IjLNZmE3aFObLT4hWeR2jVIMCSuzfVWMN7LXDCEvK4k31nIC9D9qkeGthRyLtNNs9WtoCTzQHeYsWHb3KD43k8COJamKhAcU6QZSDa4sWHDTswiBxxyvetyzfusczHNfFWeuBNemAnPWilW0RtoIL8UN8AHW8DuQ6@bOBeaNcGzP@mrDQNlS5VyOlSQVXfovvka7BGECZp0gb4bN2UllSuE053EgJbKT/taX0r5eNOnrWAr9PvrXRbvsN2y6@p3IH9vFs@Xim7gQRyBoP9yOIrKQ0qkvzJWn5cpxANS@OxSlZ2bG8idlantBdEbHUSADWBL2bHbnuW3mDxsY7GIX3GdXb62RW0l6Q@eV6TYb3n6E3H2tNHtrhEyvQRxi3ISALlkOSPWygIThQ02um5Z07mpZ15uYUWoT46xVLOSaG7HRyq9rqLp9Gt@xf8cTr7LnEO3MH@xA8W5Qur8taTFrsMIkr3o2s/m3a1ialPBSvSrtRXRpFN2cvXGPcriYqKM1B@iJpiXaZgPQ8iqlOl/3GtJ7YVhaMp3vB9nWJzegPAOuL7XhNi4v9f3NU2p40D4c/nX6HSSQ63DpA0vXaaa6aOMeAZwNQ2SZhrJkPASTwhkOElJHOX3363z0qyDaFpb@7DfQFblvZNb6uVtPtk/F1@Y9T7t6QVjuIHYUOn7rMve2Plss08ns1n1AdiYnAqZou7u1Gi/LqJJV/nkHzu7r3HZYQMYk5pKBkeLojK/Bae1OUYKlQSPiAvcc8w@zBbXF3JKN0CYUBpaL1MCOS8ZNjjRxlAHG7Q9uSVl1gs4McVA/CIln05ImTNyd6ThlovGfpikWT1Uvbv8ZxUIGJ8wj4P4Wr1k2F8XSSDG6cu9iqVD7uVd7s5kWlTdaX0bp/jkGsVSX/YQ4yQ97v7huFM7h7l1cbiwASs/R0AtEQTE/0xtc34HmE6DZtmDM44I9V/Fk/v42HJMIJ4yDbgiwVLBE15MYulF2X284oU0q3g7x7x6WeWDEJPLQz/mJ@l79oBO9awDNwhuount8lc3jSa3CdDCFDfm7qcjEaTJRuicWVJygOFbuM5CeWNKVZJYr@0ihbWXdhdLEmjr6KJ9y8m9@xHWomB9NQE7vf5ApABJ4qAkEcmQxHnKCF8g1E/uUVz2kAAvCxlEtAEEGvDxSB@kQaDifiXNOgw6cPJYAHPvH1dM2Ua/SbcV6i7x9OERt9MwFwrXCxHO1Vw1PBCEfq16MQOXEHPncA/9qpuVRz1RNRwheN3ehxRSTT8Jo0uobDbVUptR4F31I18SijYIZUs8AfDbveEe9oJ3DAUfiC8VqfpETQCH9jtyHNDS3htp9mlybpuCYIg2n4kml7Liyhb5FuMVRczsnLCr4mWGzgNerWPvKYX9RhjzYvaQFYjbLbo2EHkOd2mHYhON@j4oSvAmFH1Qqdpey23WkJ4prYv3GO3HYmwYTeba4z6J203APErXB65RKV91HQZE/NZ9QLXicBQ9uSQ8IjApiXCjut4eHBPXWLHDnqWAhq6X7uUiT6Kqt2y68ScUfyBVKhenG7gtkA0SSLsHoWRF3UjV9R9v8qyDt3g2HPc8EAYTT9kgXVD1xKIcceoCQZJi77T81E39FhuXjuiOaPbiTy/bVIln5BgiEqbilZZwH5bcktC8oMeoEIOXAGWOGm4lB5ApiwtG1IISWpOlM9GCEmIUZ5N0XbrTa/uth0Xn32AOfFC16QK80JkIJjAe2IT0i5zjXoiuuQjNVZDt1yLq1N4NWFXjz1QrnJTCwg91VpYbE5DyZz6ctnYuOX24gbe810@ZQp52Um841dd0vhkcJVClt6lSefj6ubdyjeaaNKP9Kp2QXmuOh/GF4ur82R8OcHSPC0md7BvZ1cWYgOZiDD4zXghxKnaKOcCr1@fnx/b57TODc/PTetnSq6Q8aMSygvrS7lMxeNo0h/yMn/FtpQX1OG28vVuScfLeVvLdmp8MEW5PIxVMVxeBGBtJlJBCQjYECMj32rsj0UOJW8xr9qKOGLGurFIb29OZvQz/it7kXNDLoEGZ3luoVzGGpbJQOQTkdJPSDgoiIoMwucAkktGWZrF8c1VsZJHhyW/MlCZugznndMy8Kpo/qD4RXy1VnxnvTwTi7umrKxod/DaTbuM3443JTKh6qU0Zc6K0rTHf6amhhGRUmhKVHyRVZ0@KW7L4vAvKm2F5kHqSpzDgbTsU@8Ei7nK3v7BWnojTZd9C7fOEduG5rs/uNwZ/zXOZAbqYAmWXySS5FFuqZbLuTKklbE@mWaGr/prZFomQ5pTMVVfxzytw0O@dBecL0@T8TR5yFNPw3A9sFtH3VqNRk5Qu//x/YffDgzlcX86P7Xkfw94EHyQpUta9DIhNY0/5XqJQ3pP7VmwnFx0H9QeMiK0n640TkT8@tRzptQRZHwNaQYCuzNEGBgjyEYBQQKmBYH7@fErQ7fXjT1TNYDiCqsmuLntP7CG3ydVidvAQHrJHD1yrT3gB7DT7q@7eMqQakCqicW3d/NHarm0uOBxr1DTDgd4bcPXipGlVNDt@K6vzyBJwWDMZC8MuIPPb6pt52qR9FpUNPorVzuXJCJerVOhg7RwyCVC0ZnMdA@WiQmlnKr2Ro89FRwInxDqwZ6HJMZaWnJHB@@RNmfVMRTks8PPVEXb2ymm3wUMqaYiStr/V0PH5HsDkyIPNIg1wPrkUSrn9Asbob/8aoo/ZUuFV2/AOVAtVr1Ty93EjoJyoF2iq3cdQUZIWFlAGU5apjgMnaWns6TiXBHTf5IHw/8fZbIB/u@04CTombR4HE7Gi/gnJclQpaxo9cpCSZb6xFjumFomzXxSLwPzlK@Y65QxdQzvQW4skQhU7TzqhJ4MKVbcIAA0ctg18v0XDny5E1/3aeX0hfvuL3Knfzoe3N4VdUAuPVU8g3tmsc5l6SNyeDHlFn5F5NA1EV/lC/t55DEDCy4axS4exdasIGG83eUxB0yX37DRI@3l3DQhhl3dw7PmVFFdS3f@B3XCKJtlhvrrE6mi3w/2lW6HIKbQyoCvd0D0AMJnn/IMK7ERzkMQupFveHphK79Qs3iMYfNSzssiYvccs/4lr5kxFSlfGnDaAZSAszVUMZsu4vkS08VIQmcfIhk0UdxiNyZAomyRqRqhB1@zRFLnSXaZUs9mSrTXlPru@GaMqLaxNHHpHKWVCFB5F6wl0epzMKjRz/FdyJC/hVgPV/F7Y/arMpD7lTDN8cqdsGClvzXLJEIa5xLaJc1DmZT6gxskFnQbTZY7yQP9Ma4dxbmOaURrBo5Yt0npf/ruggBtZe0MrCh8G6dGpE9yIvu8pdUXPMm@mz718KTszJ@JKSKOUnBgVqlBIBl6Ew5pPu9tTN8/)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)

### Explanation

Deltaplex is an image-based language with graphical output.

As it turns out, Piet still works if some pixels of black wall are recolored, so part of the wall can be used to execute Deltaplex:

[image: Deltaplex path]

```
(x,y)  hex                                                                        [stack]
(0,0)  #FFC0FF  r255g192b255:  NOP
(1,0)  #E60001  r230g0b1:      IP direction down
(1,1)  #CAFFFF  r202g255b255:  push two 8-bit unsigned integers (first G then B)  [255 255]
(1,2)  #280000  r40g0b0:       init everything, pop window width and height, show the window []
(1,3)  #CA0000  r202g0b0:      push two 8-bit unsigned integers (first G then B)  [0 0]
(1,4)  #E60100  r230g1b0:      IP direction right  [0 0]
(2,4)  #CA007F  r202g0b127:    push two 8-bit unsigned integers (first G then B)  [0 0 0 127]
(3,4)  #330001  r51g0b1:       draw integer 127 at (0,0) (pop n; pop y; pop x) [0]
(4,4)  #E60000  r230g0b0:      end
```

Notes:

- r50 (go to 2D mode) is not needed because r40 already does this (see `screen()` > `initGL()` > `set2DScreen()` in main.cpp)
- r41g0b0 (redraw screen) is not needed because program redraws itself every 5ms at the end
- Popping from empty stack is an error.

As with Gammaplex, there is no instruction to quit a program. The program is ended by entering wait state that does nothing except refreshing the window
every 5ms. User can press Esc to quit the program.

This Deltaplex program contains a bug: on Windows 7 SP1 32 bit it displays 127 as expected, but if the window is minimized and then restored, the number disappears.
This bug does not show up on Wine 1.8 on Ubuntu 16. I think the program still qualifies for the challenge despite the bug.

#FFC0FF is `+` and #E60001 is `-` in Braincopter, so Braincopter code does not need to be changed.
 #E60001 is op 6 in Mycelium, which modifies color of pixel (0,0). Position of the pixel and new color are popped from stack, and popping from empty 
stack returns 0 in Mycelium. So this does not change behavior of the program because Mycelium never executes pixel (0,0) again.

I used `_` instead of `,` to be able to place several `#RRGGBB` colors on the same line and not break DOBELA. `#define` and `char*` lines are swapped for Retina.

Comment: I wonder does ImageMagick ignore the `_` or does it understand C preprocessor? Probably the first.

Comment: @Potato44 Yes, you are right. Turns out ImageMagick does not understand preprocessor in XPM files (XPM3). The image still works if `#define _ ,` is removed. 
It also works if underscores and commas between strings are removed.
I find it weird considering that [XPM1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap#XPM) used preprocessor directives. 
Probably preprocessor directives were not parsed properly in XPM1 either.

Answer (score 6):

## 130. [Boolf*ck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck), 5050 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"    ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉QQxQRrRrRrxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(4O6O@?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o<
>-}

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="23 11 24 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezgggggggggggggggggc"
"fiyuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggxgxgc"
"fkTOOOOOOOOOOOxggggggrc"
"fmbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyt"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyt"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flyggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_"
"OOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOl__";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{      function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp         v (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002298 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5166 bytes

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgHdKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQBvErXW2t1NiUShKisrKysrK6sqUejy5uAPfzjAD13VlEVf0SzaEk2L7hnyVDSCdGZBf@ZlMxoKUxRCpY3@ZCyqlnlMHdAcTcuqIPfgnra0kajKS9GA@BBN64bWN/gxbQ14ixZNgddFk9Ymlj6xaE3any1M0/mxNpQDmHMsq30As0RDN0SLpEdouqkq/Ljb41@lRF8VqBuQbtI5Ufll/ItFC9p4zKs9EyBjNJ2rZPKl9CsMcZq@1gxTRDyCaJoaRiZoep4XhVegSQDlDVkrpcvnr5I4lj4H0nldEec03zUtgxcsWVNt3lUNrTcRsF7WQIScyAtJVkSTEoDmM1p3WiCIAfqANkS@Z4NRkmbQmIUejxRapgVdp7sKPwgKtCIDbIFN0CKyjl5CujIw6bk@BgymNha3STRpVRR7tKmLgizJAimdFueWqJpApRmkZWFEz2RFoXuiAhk2JAl@QEZPzK0om4Ag1dMoGj6C/qoC67tDEWBUccUEUQfuIRM0ZDZwZMWLmcHrOhAJjKwD4ZY8BpmRLbdJi7wpo1RCFlNUe4R/@lpeNZpXt2tJT2We5oHeiUFwm6KBjRAkeOmBaIiAkl9LjGdmyBawANmbpqsib9ANQxS9u7K7UyQUpmEJFlYkSJrv9NSdrxTc0Ix2jiCvW9SBEW7cXFI8HUzRh08n8E25XCdUvpyjvxw@YNgWVWhq3fDwXjr1G9pkHh5E@M65LtM3XijASgFXFJrRdIvhAzoQGLCAQIbHIIYC01BQV7YKpk9ftcWWcNlQPWgNuqjSLT@pmTAxDOyOG6byI6i0oql94CdU1pioyA@VjrHQBIIGvclPi1PgmqbabaTNCIcbAxkazcQm2eoAtlIhDAW1ArLncHRVrqkpEwIHOU0LBRC4AlkRY1GiW7TEywpmgXREZVNtiOZEsTDPRO1hy4PSEHtBekWGoPUQaKxNoTgekJII6EvjrR5IiAJgaAiNVBWTfvev/12v3wc8aUHQjJ4jri26pwlE/fGEWNApNAqspvIKIQvg/Fi6nR0KmPKK3OMtLF5dOEUQIkipM22i9GgNCjRmMnStAT@F7ihJomCJtpDbGtNPj/mRrTdkW3Kh4mO@Cw1LCiBlk2oH6M9ZaCVBpA6IzATGE0tK0AE9T7tN5ifPp2PPp48PIhDnDXqPDhmmfwICFzwiUXDn/prktNJbGg2Ui8Wbmtyj9IU10NQQHRBol5DSdFH1uHdwuP1uo@v2BlGfebwnckoISrLa87hBxjNQrtt7IqSEe/n48eRV7u0SAcsMsWBvFT2C10WBxiF9YsqMeVkN6gu6FXBCW2ma@YQcx@TgVjTy5XXc1I44IAMGiqWG8gFqKGgqoqh72CDnRS2BcHurjQn7KvoKh1PhY/nR5z5w@7arTjBATXcqin21IWuotRR9MAEdDUxRTR20t4GiK/AgPCYqcQtGbT/dJWJNND8oFqISZ6LbEOku6NGVGJEeafc4zB9APelg2PSgFdxuhxZ7W/0ZdAF0act8o5QVbQYFE9pw@AINomLhfB@aCDLbFUrbFbJLJDG7VRupoFcQW1ekE4GuDH0Bex2odkf0t@oI4OGQDQPY7L6ypYLG/AKwCPaQuOk3tCxBlxqDljAWtCCi6gEdJNrjChYyId3QBHsFLRc2EIpGd7vam55mGUw6cAe6esl8tUNh5dM7VgIMQJI4oxVe7U/4PppMKmThBUHULUdfQU1MCzTS62GHRAacMTRoDqjDz6/LJmOJM7pulYG63m49Z0TkUck4RlNAAZ1K847ZR/dkA7STsnhdOgBMXxXu@hlBdgj42fUOCStDAIRMnIvCxALlBoI8G8jCAGQXqVNt9WiPRa@Lh6jt0kHBB6R10UgMd/ZjiAoy6ygk410UAWzRt3hgjEVUZzsRpPG3I76OmTfHexBraxJhPNiKDTJ8EGTPYRpYT3W03GCwWZlKpGetzbk1P4HB0NWhm4KwDCxLN49Bt8vWYNINQrMyDWNRtCoqtixjGQvZ0uxwV9G6oEtN6EzMqgRGmHTl@asakbg1w4cmNQWjSTLpFIy2zxMQEY9bMkHLkfgsAm8luYi2JSjsXxcAEqAgcMojmUR/FkAD1Beq4HEFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLVhujyqDbZDBH6yxjgJqRQLU4iproaX7v8LRW2MQWc7uDQ01WPV/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75X6Fee59xGab41CylHUPf398HH708/eccw3h1Qt6CdQQQAfwAnjc3lQKg16v62wGFQ12Jbv2NZuzPSINNVHtU@Jc1wyLLldy@adqunGRcjET02AUucuoMBg@jaG7wcTDtSc/zCBW2SFY0zQrRRoM4wl0AYCcmRVlaRPooDBZkMeyVSRTFUVF0d402io1C@VuEFRl0aKcoWMj8Thr2bQN1IPAF7cnMJKhjdfqyKREYaDRrsOwCw3vnckjjtFOagRTJ87UcSs@jvFjnPYFBaovCHRAs2/XkQ5gAgFxKhiEmRfV9/kQkkwN15EOZJKgxOlh0OiuIr9w7AvGr@eGW0p/G@O@9PczEd7smcw6hcawxJ7WFZV5LBIQFSlozZdBVAuxCGVf6EDvPYg9ean5cl8GyoI@HphLrxJ4g7IpbMDAUoJ5BF2STTL3325Oat0RHiiX3VHDu0OGa5MS2th3@41S1zYWIrQgCCMN1eIm9AQWWHQHBcyp3@aUZHNAfnZA31D0NoXkNsddifzsATh2DB0QfZx1I0succ6GtpamwQx9RsDGmqrZpACrZJVnauQShPFxHz27w9AOMV1RmsA8junKKoa/ARZIJgik1O3K74ECX5D01XUPmDHp7mMbCNfgjaVC7zDemhiWIvac63/74x40wNvmGfALmH8Io3XgCfiGTRWQ3m0tJyvekJ/9LUtghhNF5gkbSOhbKAUe54i8sg7sR42qlw4EBrwBjbtYNS4IJ/7AMPoVObMpN0Rl0hNX1/2FEBbv2kN2blUekxrBFY07Ml6@k/2VNWfnxzm2oWh8j2Cx1z5kcdPadruIc74PlWO2NBJowu@gc2V00ZvFDjBYrIn9i@sb32pXWcfv1/qrA8lG@S4nwsyQ78rvcBGJiL0n13Z3QQMjICn8yA4@YXB/Ve3KGHK/D4aVc30PDExemJXovCAyM3J5V8WoE1O3mwJDX8FnKPbveyCrxdh14D1AqKZCfn6N2BFBEKBvIKm4vhjYYpH8iqkK312gETb49fKDBZJxFNRLSvD52DAOqesJ6WYlU9ffz482AMmfTO7PbS96EgSCJkmi@K0@C@OOPOaVQKi3FXxXBa@M1k1oD@iQn/Jgziq8CQJiOWwWp9As5OdrQotDiTBReGMT@orIbshZrTu8N3Xd5NFlQVNkRzJXN@/pwtfziA0aXNYmP5usePeWvz0w3XGYDqxD@zu0Jlg4fXxHjr5DPdkzN5wbbwlGUHuPd4I2w@@7vXegTUX7d/@QtdxL1Xeon4BCJAOmg2@z94RviSuuQ5Kf/Vwc7aXKEpS98cf0taYZMHU36VCQRQNHJYvnMGArij07bRQr78u0KSuaSdfJ79d4ASa/adq/@6V5m20yrwaEgd3H1uH92fYSRYY3Ok1@32lcXulrSizRZ3j4eVcCJoaEWt65fq@GW2sojvumhlqbO5rKOdd3VfsI/r8lHGRZ1MAFiK3gV6yoferMmbi@X0GYEeAS4P7KFdgEyRlk7Hnaew1gCIMZv1hd/xGjx3vcXY0e@oIYy2DNYYZkAgKWYRvQ/5jSIl8vrfd9OuoN2vi3KrHVuCNFBI1Nft80KR1iuV@Zg2PZ79dYkjIRJ@JeDVLpDkUQm6/pju8ninWqceisbDDAPNwxXUMtnangd1GN4znefVXh8IoMnfyb1sxeVaODha3j1LkKgSoG3mbsqxN9p3G3eFebqLWvc26gr3q21tshElN@rUZKfNtm2jHDTZF89yuQY/QFgAmvNgYbQv2O9neQkkUg@3cHMYnZYB7KuB5lfBXvMb1eqQT7FewRaFV5ZAZwUev7FE/ovZk6AU4mYS6mitYCf9/j9j5F2tU05de0DujTnoxmGhif6DrwrVY6puuLcRcsN2GzjPodLbCaJgK3cEr8bsNWAaX1nTjDb1f1vjJKba3x7S35XFPOTs@@0eg17LtcMBGMfxVwtdzFrALvdEGCLBkMf4/5o69sWrJiiqus9rrqxrXh4JV60RfAGLkXMIWBOBbJ7VcMer43nJiry7tAcw2/e5KDDFnzfCefLkN/VvF3Zw13JVGWpormV5lAarVaO93LzeKY74uFb0rOZgEB9xIFQ94J7l9KOLZFXYBs31AL9rROU0fiwlxd9xu/CwEacDL@KrZ9nVbAdcpv9tIgs3e9@Bs2nDrQBupAHBiMaQibu/d6DIigZbszfb3l1AFvjnDzNHCbrVa3Jm0Dc5u9iqYo39S6GVBv31IPzsYF8UpZb1yafsedBuJkw3GeMNceSgdFVTBEso252imjD3BzdTKGibClGUGawHk8vM/n9VJ2JpxL9VUAW0ERHxHcOLbdT0waZrgWgZUl@v6ePvwyP2aPuRc6RbuOXfTjo42VbGHm5zpx7qjZWe8P@cfUoTsQcB@6H9RjmnUTUFEB03YvKL8DJ8nkYtO5qTqt8mOyV43hVU1P7A1xmHGiz8mAV3uKSDdBV5N5uGbY27q270ADl17/69/3HFecvgiVHMsmmDJ9Fd3HtLE40Gaf7HKd0tO6zqMrD@KYDXBtEUsPZNO0OZMt0E7EAwcmxM1CI@Fs6DsObnBTxS67RYXdqDhMoJuJZTeaTU1PE22xcApe51pVStCUyVilZ3LPGphBmD6qgkgcBta7RhBCMNUyUBx7frpI90Rc@uohYUQ3Kpo2ItthSMl//XvbjQESZRQhDK@KJ15MWyXSqO@J74AgaBOgeoVkKRqaA@JBJkN3naBVAUIt2vFeWhjwxL8CJDGw8i7AYmwPg2y6TgfytBu98HAb9ESWPIfp2nnrnn1M/YYeM@J/@2PG@8Xhm@uHQJwzXX56BXLygnK1ncxC8ibVTbsO5y6nWujvRdyb1kLlOG96MEyaa@UtMCauYkTuxBnxFiD7eipqI/TBUk3oH3DrJajtTpM69EzsMS5Qt@gouirCsMFDyHYuI143uPONWQ7n9C/0AGUlINBclIU7myEKOluMU5nVxkV4e2@JyYndCVlpnYaCoXCKVOfwKQXjP4YMsaeh79P9Tw/zEBt4mMfzj4y5Ys7Dw/wHNnQL3NMMyPUjgx0oX859OQyesb/8YsKc0uV6cZ/Ye23Qyw@/VIvVfL2RbjTrwM0Xu7IHBc0Y8xtNgbKgKzDbH2gKcSoDthiyaH5be6w1yPoOwD0e@pCnT9Ht1OtdJ6xBHVa7Aq5DO7gGgWFpO/c3su/Lb4pb6W8BHM0kybSjRekqESRHZtzmtgb1r2QL2wW7@wR09oojuH26RxUSHrnoFHApAFz6Th7Rb2tpt@AnEgHN@G1GfR3HPhTAqw3EWwBk0rosrK@dbldub@Vf/hlqrMO49k@tMcHx1RojxNdqDICbbCRHIV0sNWv53UwgThsP4vwcbB1QxBLpW7Yvoi1dmuP3ttJMMPAMbO8YXtnoVpOeyqbcVUQibxKODAooF@yOZMPFRO1CoyIL0mnFBE3e64Fq6i4s1Gyg0oNki93eZw@otOsAmBVcD7R@2kUhrJl66/8EmmsG8zHhZzvzIYEjmE1qj7/mg8j87l//O9tH88GC8J86YQnC/8oO/8Qgg976mdk0rlmDbGkVq7QJw6Vd8TE/36oTjlg4IsrqRKTlMXBwShiC4Daxm/pu8HjuW8BPaARgJqpe1LakPNF49KDj0THDoIHRB4MuSLZpxTm0Ayhr4of0PEGfWRggmFg0FuEYIDIwXSEMyDbCgG4j9HqPQdaoqaynfu4K9OnpKe0yYV4upmInNiOZQ/6nsOvnNaGHAEvZtsg9DXkgyyYHpJ052TyHvI/zYlbscm7OTT@egJlhtwuMVB4SABAvRqsOP1wwFGoOq6DRVXFuEXW@WNlYYOCoxJ9EtD2nV4gCgMjGja6dr2V3s/@HXhFb0hzcbgZXG8HqCHbs2ic69z/RD9aD@uh4@NIgMP9hjyCpEP6zPW6/a@lJv3U49bx2F8Xa0J/rqoY7wgWglvaEmFCY4WLerZ7iclABvdgvfgGU0BOgZwmiPNR0M53NFy8r1fobh0kC6X4N5qbdZ6e@h0DQf/@4DrhfSf2KqZkCU7/OFFas3KZqs7SCEJv1lddk7ivtNaXvlN62N1/flk0S3hTEsd@LmEypAgWyBPkW@yaV2QLM2ptDb0r1eL@83D@enj2oB2@K/2WfL/lB8AiFC0IPJvEkd9N7dE5xtaXcwAd9zODKOynk2jwpsfa9su830e@7Ua4fG9o4U642r9GVMnTG9MQpo04UhQq@s60NdQ8ydlHEj9AmbEUv6JoVqRySuilQoN5sDW5TQzt1efuEk@NOtmZSxZ6eEp9uXoWZiSELNrRJFLQ9iSUOyDCNKVqbmQ/MpnB2TCZ4CzKZAVWx3mrryWQhgDdWfm7rlLo4lgONFT2oODaukaDI0OUPpvEDRe6e8Kn7Ob12zvqa12TQ1BXZ8qC74jyIk0SojceLFeBOFRG9HU@Tj45rJb3ygPQRJ8rqBPhV1XR6MzHPiatQDeZmdG4CyEEMRPpyMgY4iVxqIo4SIl3WApAZ@OheEXEPpXicOgTHvSiUHhyI857ch5HG4/WDSvqB4zbul7zXBxNqN@hhm1XnuIe4zZhf5TK6xTH@ng/Kak@ce9CX//gRuQPx7ll76va63sgA8Vt1nFh7rx1YV8qCt5xeu3H@fKUQksm1ItjtO8lkcGBS6DwH8woosW4ZJQjCGOqRxrxOeybEA9ikgzS59Tx4VL9pGV46cIbj2YxWaZ@PzEjgQhKCNMkpkZCs4KqZBx9y8TApaGeMNdUeXpayTt9zweAjhEkhXvoQ1xSyYG7gbNxLgcEJWY4JWhiA4e8YKZrB3Aspsq@HpFgKFwQMgNqbTDpyf0A6IPCC1Jo@@5HeaINND7S5mkweO62xqw6TNIjF6R6NAWj3qLmVxQn8dTyggGuoxAAqC1NNGRTK5ytRVaG/ekBmxtA7aX4CQmZ4/asnLP2bh3dICQc2iReOSxUQuvtQT979RdHAnjlkTsi89uQFxv2fH3Dgl5yhf8H8ERNkTr54DpXUggFjzHvmORykOF/4yOc7VI88hyqaIz/@iNPhl0Owdp6CrqBrDkCBQ8V7AvIM1lHqUD055E89h71U6IjkgFufz/sFMvzGZIJfDvkX5vBHsCb8EGPYvdNzaHqxO7DBIPcC9GEPOWT8IDNfPC7aRZ6PxOIPZZ8PaQgePiEBv2Ee6j4yrjzUGTLzPnGMXKY/XqmRXVtl3RJvnve0GehEH681epS4xtqL608r4O1nevak7bOP/vCHAy4Gk6hPsbBH@xQKfzw6oA8@u5gjl@H68pCbuu95KRR8fqyOqtVb74PHfZCtuLiICy32n2j6iKEOmCP2lzjD/Pzzz2B90vdnwbPgo/c@4H6898zP4vEjfyxx5P/s5uxJNEzIOM7rCYW8DP1Qpx/iPH/ki4Q@qyeyLOtmrwdfbYBPmIEllkIp@QAfD1d1u6Nhd/0ndFr/9Okj/JF/@Kxv8fcjiXGiCcjbz0cv7XmeUwdnH25u5jc1A//mX/88wbeSIcEWw3GhB5yxhWMfP3@AKos@8jk@/kzmMbQrnnBp2mcEpgcHHBeltQMY@eYi3aXn8wB@qANhPj9YQiJ3sCB/TxjmuDlNHfwmlfJ952e@DgWDT6sQdfDz6c@pf8KHOoB5xsHZ2ePLiy9wH/zpxHdygl/8hz66Cp6Qjx2C4h99Ad/p/elp8OxsfhZ4PLunDr5QB/MX6iDkAoF6OKIOUvPTGqHxPnfmUPvsTJ1LED4NPN5XS2AeN/yh08BBqJDO@kP1ZuaAg7vo5hYTw3hby6dzlSZAV0v5dD1/Xmzlm1WINx@fzj5/9gWB05@DZ49AyfwH35kvZVkWffd0FKS/@nnaE7JvqYPc2bzJBE6B2JITUyPFBB7g7sELhf1CHdwf3HsilVjl86fQpxCrsFOWG3Gja62y@a9UIF6es0PNYAfsgOth27Nik12wizk71ipcD4Ii/LFjCMqsNGf7rMqqHLeD5/3/cUW7rmiASoNs1py1ECsrwbVfqVwDMgkKHsKfzLLsHAics1P4ZxUih9xPTyyps5d9eKDuadfPInTwIOcOsu5gzO2WH6Mx/fnLSyj2fE@G/2jy8V6cy9aji/a7nx7uk8mk@/HkgDEfHhhb57lCEdcJgry8PD3l0o300xODqyHz00PfZ1/gM3xSZ75T5/LpoHeGnA2efnyg3J5Zu93Gb3s2ndkhErDj2uvE7RsSgM/0nby7gfl@WfB47qOPX168Xu@HB/eJ266Jx0OLYNR6XNzDPCTRIZeXWLtJGCq4MBoksaj37CwWhftYwhvwsCTZzvLg0nX9wRUks@cg8ZZIpdKGwS8IUARGqwcXbzw9uO5Dj6lUMkqio4FkjNaMQDLsdXm9P3Gnp04ZIS9Eu9xzl2a46S8v23@eLy@nHvLx4p/Xi5HO75nXA8neKNzNv3jmp55TD8ZBFOb68nKGQQL3BUL3Hu@j9@XFjoNfj/fUxnnmBd7hEsE/479m0qZOuw9eDtDKUOlI1OvpLkRvJOZJ@JLOX@ojVMDjCrvDUC@Xm3ff338@Ch/FI/efHo8ejzynR8Gjh7PHHR3udR/QIMsr2UtxB8g36iB4UnNxIZcbZfEE1/o1RQwqWp8OJ092hcH95Dl6/UlwSd@R7/P9UTJpl3109MtH6DaADgpzwecA5Jf20Kdnp2uh2qD0nsH3C@0wGcIvX0DO7DQwWjzOav7Dw5wl/dFLn3RTh18O@JcTgp9@cblPduSV4Pe4T8h2j@uL65A37rlH14vr8Ev3Ba27I85LjIho5OTkKGKH4wkIc0deewUzysLdKgwposkLpOeeHKA4uYHnXqhVqiv2ZRgI9R0m@aLRKBOC3/kPsXxoTp3gtoi9B@MKuOwORCeSBN8BbZpJCiYQXWj5GR1nYZhUFN6gNUn6aMfDTIjuiiIYo6Ki4HoeThTAXlZ6M5icfqQOQNGAmWyK8BlXeXEiirPJZCauP1nZPOaHtGcIE138/P63f/Uv4Pv38P1z@/rn/0cyir@//@3//L/97m/@FiL/C3z/b/j@59//9t/@sf0l9/8A3/9nK@4fnO8WnP2lANf/8Pvf/sXf/f63/@qv4fu/Ot@/fv393V/@J/v//3X@MPi3v/vLf8Af@wZw/dWf/e7f/gmQ@JcY/pcQhn8n@k8hSPsC9se3lU7/csiCqUU//LKJ/FP6F4YDdU8z60jA@u9/eUC3Ms6GXOH8hWE5iLYh/@z3v/03fwexO5B/ssr@mYa415COOKwK@lOA/JsdOh3IP6XidLMKP7Xi@UVj69rIp7MXVIzOVMq5V5eoAxSlS/lCY30bt1NXWaNrFJ18qfT61rl0tAkt8CheIs3TthLmYaKLZ2wEsdNS1NmXwCl1Vs83ILlRoRMJiLfv53gfDuE9dVZtYkSxTC9I@i1eq9WW6XJpcBt4oSjsCR/paNzvDwaD8INXP/mQa/DwpxUI976JckBd43pskrO3x2XMASFDTOKGIHSgmUr2Y7v41PdEfz8SLhiFQUPuD2AWONPWAKZpwtC5HkrfDKxt6gI67BgfncRn7C2cCMgSzVJB7N6hUDIRTSTDoYQ/kUxEolwsGvVzIT8XT8STrB@mAAkulogmOX8ikgxHIpGkn@ZC0WQcJoxqT5YYBoxFzuWiSUBWBXxW6BQfutKCgzPqoCdKMAv/QM89Pe@Hg94qgp4kaFc48cDSLoZxUbhdcjRPuUJhGvpBKEJztItyLWmBPmCziTALZmkXbzKJeDoWdrmeSAp8sqzL1cObOJsoZOIul4g30QTLxjMul4Q3hUKWLRRcrop9gx@Xa7G6YVkoaIB3@RiLHpsuGW@yaRtuiDehBBblco3sFPtmvLqJA5iKN@GwjeB5jQ1xG3ZJCZLJsm9YNpN1uSZ2JRLw53I1CLow/CUgkwJ3XYUXRi5XH4J9A9SqC2axAml1EFMIoXeSavEulwA3woJXIZ80sMRl//VHwBR5MenvTxk2XqXM4Y@kjBqVzWduJxokZdxdvP1YmKK@m/K8lVJZVHqVBn4wBea6/VVKf10gSdn7wRRJI0SRKZ@G16fKXHuClBW5@LGvlYry9OQ6QUFDkacXHu8XYgl7aFNeitAlPax/AuZf9NMk4YrFXcdHcHV9coUhOPfQrBsGdJf7weXy3icfP7niUdcxTG4D7h@5TzCFTLqOXfG4i/aeuELQX6IuV4wOgSjewRgo9gNu@pPrxBCtiaHSoZMXpGCZYk8IJfSzB6@8H3@73i8OWPfkBVfPgMxnz9Ln88PX@wkpBjsWTHPv8QIsB@/JC/Q5xul9EKC40xAoN8yZslfdABqkaQ1gd/t1v6XBZA8GafjCLBfT9ZTNDo8r6aHJWJ18cDmmjL0W4nG74yG32@s@ASQfadeWsvOeEJJpm7WeFX9cwBHgTxIsb4cJnmQA7EI6kIQKvCHJGB2bFm/g4hgp8Zh2xZIujMaTmJKrwj77A5z/@KgbPT377yjbTolx1MEL1cPnfyJJ@iR5gnNaMKBPz5w8V/Qi3vddbJF8Qh26kWh3eGdKcUB@D3FAPAiEtYh2cHh4CBPtxpkr7KoEn04ZZ0J8xpCZ8MPZiS8VyfrI7DK4mpGf4frCm08kQhkiemL08Dwme4qSiCJr@rR5AOhOfP@YTxDKTQFS6gStWNeBjsIvKAtc36AfbFpPf3NA5jB09YuzMT5Rydr98TWu1Hr44zp5yvL@kfb@piwrXxLhwBlZ6kJRo6GtXurJn@I/JX66blaalcJn9jhxnHh4cBrEz7k5N2H202cYIORanjowf/FqUe436uXJwbHuDkfcYZh5pw7sanNx78FZKB40@cXBo@NQ5onEUdrgnli0IY4@kNq7n9nOzXRMViegqMQf9fp9OfRH1z//csgwbjdNc4ex3wRO7f9T@KGzFbsQVyzq8qKrnfnT009PBzRYprQrFEVp9jG0bXtuLOUp7ZkfqT8dqfAnHpnkTxTJrXp0egZRJkQ49yJCiN4jhmFaIRhbk8lYInZA/YFhvrZNBanrdVtJFA1zMt63cJs25GseF7XV9eItBK4nS9GA6@qEpNUgTOMojDsTOAxvxzkj81YUOVhsN25hMugcg7FgDeERVORkOlpCFeHBuZdFnBzoIzzWDX0AvdQX6gPgmggW8auBnxOK@oAOHnjrWcH56R9Ny4ub36yX@vDBUXmmFTStJ0SOmZzIAHdCgTEG7OF7PZPGNXWyl207DvLoLqHptqu5sqDtTCbR6bZFQXz@sNwtgo9oyaYCanNEkxIJ5Vg5u/gPNlh3IiEphWIpD3noFC2RvRknt8vo4pkgpHofJa9TOM1CFGJBcMIpAo6AgA4iPQS3d4zeiYKHQPpoDtMlsscDUGBf@QklflpyMt7j7SNkR/SSoGgmILZL99g1oI@enGKdOqxGEqwEsBBrR/QzGW6MvuB3Wg8fvr5/9NJfVj5QHkylT@nQxknLwQWNYZ@9RzIK454tOOSwFYfNBBv36IemPbF9aTxrOCdmw6gX6sjyj0/sptJPqCuP4P2CewAnvxn/@KPwk34/fjzxjlMWXn2@MQwXI49sgxxZqXEKxEO/lx9PrHufT35Mjb1XHryHkQjG1xdKspltep26Qc3VFNCC@4Sm17@8VwO/UR/9hXvVByRP/Ed3qaWfT7H@OXzlFOdX/M8pzqkHlGmllj71hD@FL25H7PgpwdDp4092ojDLyKOklvf8Ywr4oUBGn68AlQE6zXvF53v0QuEKJL7NeKL8@CPvU87mJ0og4EWon8KfCvcWBB59Kbw/9vCn80/L@wnkP/bANQXFKF4gHvI5vH5Z0w70nQCP7TbdkG7TOEfy5kDeOJU6uvt0dHeU@vhxeT8PjB/9NvuP2Y00IPFzJP5kyw/Mc3TnpV@xhKyHeFw/yMc/BI9M2uWXwZQ5uvPrWzltCo/uIEWHwc@h@gX1JTkSbLXVhRLm@C7Zh7KQYx3IFJCcXGaS0xqtHnpxQt60KciyA2673@oyTJ54fCTAT6uaGuAJBKY5RxRi4sP80ydqVbTjWAMlo3Lp4pwTJmHkhCoDF2fIcZe2k/@39Os@NbzSuesZUb14l6dh9hWObXVXoppIhzMN4R5BUA18YV9ObI1lu1OBsiHaA2CI9kC4AGoRZJKjJxzIlJMIrbVqIMiFekKyXeXxVBAT9ROot03PBxVikwGdeQ8Zsn@YIroJ5EmGEC2fkvIgAF2F@gCVQBqwDvIjfQaKjP7xR9q5PU3BjDKOYwGCIdzQxyHQG0qh8O@gFHAglUOQUdSHpBCg7QOmoBPgTkGRf1pBjg@vBzL4hn7blTdIXHk9E9W0PdiRb16bDGyLDx@GYC46BME/MZchP6S9/OHAGe6PwVi5rjYb@dp1ug6/YPYnNqcgHq/Py3tz8JaOB2p1ZZW4vAl8jRM7lwLMFsDyA5HSengaZo@@bJZg5l/O@fFZS2D9gb2oAgPq8RqTaJITbMygZvSZmTySmd3zcvHkQuJdR07nDayOMURyyOCsbPzqN271Ji6AwGDuPCC2c5DqWDRN5zyxwOo8VXJmLHnCYIyO8tALnfPHiOPCau@V7PTjuqSf@I8Ycl8mh2QObAQ7@clRUZadnfQPCs8N6/EWjxJNJWGifkyzfgxwq0BoFQivApFVILoKxFaB@CqQWAWSToBbYeZszDA7C4djm2B8E0xsgsl1MMJughsMkdAmGN4EI5tgdBPclBZZlxZLELz0wYqbpOuKBqZxkcQqDZ@LUS0SGQU03OvICBAaegMJ2SNvIqG8xG5kPMk6BRWZCgKFQrHNPWifFWzKY1Plt@nw2yXbd04kjFWUPdMhAps3DNBK@TmeaghC5z2m0U@YokDt0oIi8mAMiBZYKakCyL/oPbafnzEWxxtfYcSQ4tb3kB0PEoM8HDmg0xafPcmhfck2ttBebPYDSPSaMVuO1g6RNpXHOyOtjTGyE7eN9SMqWOToOxAhGwLbYNcze1Vmw5jsLTL89SJ3EO4t8g1RNt7ovlzIGw9BnlplJeM/wZZalWfbKSJpbTADnNOYiQy8alB8kCr1hTt2/f63f/2/07//7V/8Lf27v/nb/@8//08Y/k/483@CzUKH1gB//hf48@/x53/Bn7/Bn7/cykTgw8eu3/31f4Db//E/0r/7F39hJ/2bv3P5I2tEkIJRm5x/9S/x50/w5/9y@aNrwL/6MxsQs7j8L9SOaeUBqD//LzQNpSGWNbK//nuadvnAwPA4kndv9/HHrccubARrNtyT0OPrdPtXGBjIdtbrcwFe547b3PmwAbxbyA0ejxfe9D0wZ2x3P9TSAi8M0LXeidJMtH8ENGE0M9gHeZv1wOhxlgjcUPv/nj6m3T6EgWjy/FjK1uFO/Z16uzapCOtzMUAdHgLooMKwd00JTG8pkG8yE1iYQZy2kBkpZ8uIw98yHl@@GkBcK8mSLQ/npZyyVrlh0kM7p8DC/2aqi0KLw5D9/BU5jZlyvMS5rQJ31M2rZoNSXsfAlHHzRMZ2VhIhjnVoEsi25jcyFm8IF/yv0W1azuk2@UrhVYfBTxdMzNG2RloXlKJdrm/AIqcdeC9aXOFdeJteB@CePQ4/7jzfsQ/YdXt766K24liUIaPnIRi2KmWrjHUSt5sU2koKbSUBzTZOomuiodArGsjAgXpx91kmO9uWitrNthEu7DmrdkAyYC5oLwr6JWViDlJvURONvKvs3iLfQsk9ppx@8qASnXNGu7xvMgDO3Typ1225HzX7BuZtQ@3Pidzeidlprfcx7eTZ6hSEe9RrLq1bjkvua7ndAr@Cmnv0fWdBIfafWFDgOwuKRb9d0Otmxbw76N/n77fVzkpNrDX8Bpnd8Q92BigcGv8aRG@jjpBigwQ9XpjypJ0pT3em0Z49JwhDPLM6bGHn2GBj6wgGnMSUNUu0lwc@6xpMOTS0grfeEbDvhR7Okfx9VTNEc/u5Ldn2gVfd@OSgoPVVGNX8eOiD7BxgjVuy9jPiu@PKemRzrNCs/doBRG0zCi3PpydZla2nJzA@Fcm7YSDeBgV0THZT@L4CCG3l96xN24ru0fCwGsv7bZzE3rWzNWRh5KnoTqIbCknTMKETRAUmX/SAF0b45g3CEqwieYoKLdKu5fEiEwfaWOuLqoYPTWLuV@iLG9xIEK/rhBY/zftpYYsiZxLtEfy818l69auz0lchD@9d5w/tIthhhp82XvMYOWvsKe7p3eLsbKvy6r@e3vo2vfWv0yvJhmm9pplE4moPXn9d0WHPBgMAbsgIf5sMv/Oc9BtydkhZR@PJ3HaG7yaxJ5oCDH9IaRpA0w54UAL58K/vTLhbE956j/9fb8BV9vz3Nh8xZusL0DfjPNp@ZIpmklMiVEH0AHjRi7rnbXFr0c59Z1nORIfM8Py0iyguFf3boWPquqia6/3WFeJvyDz6iryRe@JAkrIT99BkTP30KPR@E@WeeqLCL8Sex4H0b@Fd1bgm8j2ir76v4qjoiNLT7OPYPayf2zHFyHNIBOj4HZHh/VOv932xskHktfSQzThCYfF9/pGFu9eqGRdBU/YeiGaABj0gBxCQYx/0hb6wn11U7Fe2OHrUHn/slizjI53fZAjwwX4hB@ffFOv9mvqsedZV@o4RYQ0b3K0yPp60wogPCL1tw1/Hom/XlKwyrDOlVq28Y5281@Ly11p8SypWMmlbJd8nkt8Suu@WuS1Rs5FtVFj21w0hbzBneUURBM82Rjvmqy2mqW90AsZhi2nqO6PK0x6Fus5JNJ2Fh@2mbPvCS8kQLMJ1CtcWXBEhzEGfbIFa1Q3t2tWSF0kZ8/qW1eLE3Atoi25x0bu9j7gFRa3CuJD7si5TeLdM4U2Zwk6Z6x6wW@QWECXsFOm0AjbP15pAESXrHe2MSThzh8vX1DZ8VI03cO/1i1t2H8t@2j11H4NCdovu47wHlLK75z7OkYDpPq6TwMh9fAWBTd9y/@I@XnULBDDglgQ@Y7yjwvFecB9nPd4Xiryoa1Vu0H28blOA@WTfEo682MurXWfXX1uvqoqi3zYq/TRKjAkXDat1/@gnXxb@Cahzqg8kfkzRoSMCjBOQnUFja8Swy4FhI0jeBOTZN3wcr5amnPWNzRoKpPtSW4sqKCUToo/cB@5dZWQThqlk8RGuQCDqzeP9FNHcm5nZt8hxSgcJJY28Wz7hXpDYAz0PSb8H4O1FHGWTf9VeuyjsBvw@OjHze3S@IWdVHKEInQG8e8hCpv7s/kqlsK1fnRBjt/52C71dI8BGDKxA7FYiaLd0OthwaJuSwnRN3xUSkoq7ffJ2Hvw4nRKl91U2ohWcnvlOMol2aoaKYbvze79Wna18SNqOCsLEe/bR7mXrcYHoYkza6LotS9XufEDCls7pkYe7RRTbnBMkcLa68ZOx4r1haJXXLpJorl01CZmD@CTNhLfs0jf7Mvh8za@bvq5yggkONCKCrZzrUmz9qv0K@12z7feVQb1iwqsC9hnW@4fSt@b1V0fZV5Qrm2LfNiAm@umcd69xtC5hw3KYHWxZ5l@TtTcmPr59wTby7ULX2F9Z@yu2recE3@Db67mFjQutBGO6GznChdlR6H1GvbVIlGlwZbQEsSQHj13xNaWbqn2dVrvi@5oYU3CMhsuvbmBjt4G3Gw/xkQoYr1hu93J8WxXZp1j3bVxT39q5sHcdNPQSW593tBUJ6p74r61dtCCi8lTLVcqlDgy68Xjc@3YrAnst5N2M49RXtwnW05aQHw@3IC@8RN@JgWZYHx9U11uXMhIBxgBP9m1s8XP6uNfRZVv6/FXfhXw27BZHHVyjTTfgd7QSmjo8Dtmyw1cLGCJaniPeQbIyb4HffjJbw10jlA7c0Hl6IsPX0xM65zw9OaMYNs16G@kPB84bZkJbb6082PVmeueNwbgAMBnb70x0FuCcZ8NtP5QDfD/p@n3D61wT1ZJXzg64PoRbVGvPCE@Y89qvNV3F2G8fBUn1hCI4hQ1F8cFEOxdC48Inca10yvloGzp48KGpa6rzetKR/QpbcgyjuVp6JWRP1BlP3EDsUsjzlFsU2Q5Zq30x8sZBclar/XpHXrWXkFe88dNiP0h2fEJJmHKMZN0@@2jt@mF6SSZCMPHRAh53FXGMb/0D2d2zmnwtQ6sMCnK/D4LEOKfe2g4uDXwRYECTAtnNO5xb5N2Nzplxjk8YOa/RWQcGdnp2DmUw6VAMrKmkHzi7@QJj0U2GxoMXWOKkRaDgG4dL3A4m/Ft5P3oW3t0rt/p4Ed9HzxO2rP30lgyto4DIq1t8dh7q2lqadjYtiR7Y2rlcnS9COefBpMg@ZRB91HSP68C1OnUFg7bbBK8Iq@MKPHhQxjH1QSWKBz3AaMH2rQEDV0WjjWyvedcuqSr9Ax0OkXdxQXnESiXFAg57Z28HO6RBViTW9u5zFIzrh57rB9xMpD4coC60ZQ3zr0QZw@T0uI0s0x8ddPaGCnZluwusbqJbN2GYanzYU/BHj8sHWHwur2sHE8A7ux8fbM37NisoRe8fmEYv1i5o6XS6MeaM2nm6nx6kax24z7AlX3sYyTNM/kLppXPF7uJcizemUohtdG4y3bCvGu/NdflinL3Q85Qc6Yx9d@F58iKyjGbD2bTA3krnJSkSz95Kt6aYVsQkMx2ObnpiTe9yhilfla/LtSVTaN60@jdD6a7dHsbVOqXX7jL9m7l4k2ir01YzWTRvxFa2bI3KQ2vCLSrxdqw5U81Mq5EZXC6Ks9G8GNM6cjR7I8Zbkn4xExZRXbhoUnfTxiBWv1iMkty4t0hnzV4n7vMxnWymn7gQenfSZT171esb0W50VE/y4en4UtIXg6sL9bk0zNangk8fFoqxKaVWi9OZGGmPusqFeldrtbq5THU24sw7vTeMtK8nVjdhxMLhSVocDCPR4sQyEqVM@ipu5dLFVkG5bVl3i1aiSlkXViPevBSSim9asYTwJNdkTLY1v5Sv6rPYRaihXaiXSnFYHZ1PzquKPhnlInKlMY4Y/dtCVwuFLm7q04tOiTIil@1OojYMJXLCXGCuopo2DjeS5ZJxPZ9knitiOyvUM2I3xmait3lueF1ZCJVpqVZrV/V2cxw3rzjlrsAOqcqtUE9nRoXSOME1yoti4rxYn2Szxfm0G5L6WnrSa4evb2OzUlkstm@Y8AU/sa59craiMMPLS3PRal4Vb8vmHXTr60s5Ii3mmVbGkJ5zWfO6VmLKxmhQjwzVnt6Ky1lNuKwWI1ZxlL6Yte@SxcxIlKrdkTZqtJX2xJJzQ6ZALbKjm2ZXnBXk5YzPR0qtG2aYrwlWPN0P15mhJHVHSsVc9s9Ly3590u33kpVzNic@X/UyrWgtr3PXBTNSVhdUp5GR5GXtRuJG1eRF8a6bT8vXajRbFfXq@cV0Hgp1ZKk6iy65@e2wEJHnQoQtVTK3176by1DNV/JlMlUtXOlToVzhvN2PXvm0grhkShL/HM/6jMkkMs9N8NWRpaaqGOOowiYKDd8gbhrt5PX1rGsWb2vZtqAsE3fXo1HsrkbdToumZoQSl4V0kqmOWOOcH5aLd3FZLURmmXMlnyy2l82ElS9NlMRFqZ@7rBm5xli4Teb79cVi1E9citXSKE2JiVytNuz2W915p25WF@x1RBh2ffnzfPm5D/24VS@ELpuZWH9SC7eucuq02ij4ltptu6RnyyMuX01MYo14eExN55eJdN1SZT13fp2M3UzkUj6d6zeznCaKt8/CFTfi640FmzDjxk3h9kY3fVajq0W6g0x4cXPdYVp3phm9kKm7eTtWTI8M4ao3ty7NeEMNaZUblruRyk0lOm3Lz52qNkyPmavm7ZLpzpaFedUSrPpIi/bi0dH53Hw2llfGFZXoDHmlWc5qpaEQu@rIyzgT5dRGJytdC53LEJtu9i@uxcLFtL9siuPQ8OJ5ciHwgllNd7rnSmw6131SODEtUY1y@7Yff35mu2K5k5TTo2atWrRCDZ6ZdOql6HOpY5oFoVmUMxFZneQynfPROHu34BvmfDlpxLqKtKgaITZPzcud65Yw1PpmwbwThsvbwp16PQnFbitDKW71RtxY5kotiY2X9Zov56sq593@ItaaiFMBLEP9pqhzmfRwWKEq3Dg@zSySpqWem1flbvYyLafTpUToRg/FL0bZ84t5T241W@WLHq9F7rrZcKzS7bOhXqac71cj4368Wo5HSlmq0V3c1LheLiFzA17JDi8XET1ZCmViTGtWu7gZNgZqWcmm23MpExYa2ize5iW1KS5jceaa9Q0HyUs1zUaqMapp5axmqTAL@9Sr4nWoulgIt11@Eual547pEzrLwbLSEnlNGZSea1yjNSll5eGwFcsIDbaSqbOTpTnj9VKVSuaqKpcrzaeF2aDeZk09d6EnuvNyL1util29F9albiU9l9hpu313c9OsqOPbm/FFLd6tLHv8MNqypFqsMreoZzB5WtNSs9Cd5yRTGtamz@r5fHLbYiLN83Gp2Zv6hsm7zjQs31bYUjnTkvhJ8aYft5rluX59qUgKMw5V@gw1a1aXS0tMa/ny7Lozl1rLZVrOmM/c/IrhS@fF3K3lS@YL6VylUecNpVI5L@XS/Hh2PSvdxn3isn7di8qj5zuqqqpKyLirK/EMGzZDzWhumRWG5@zkPDNuXDaSnM41L1rX11fcQBHGQrxTycXa10I7nb68WlxKfKta1atXzQZV8am3d3cNptJQSkmpVKw1tGhxaly323F@pqVveLYYGXdnpXlmdj2ZtMfJS1/HEvmwthRFrjZTSox4AbKToMTJtJotV81F6Hk5fO5Pc9ptK5nWz2Pp7ELqTcXpkk3npj7GLMxnvZisJ0KNzvxc6gjX/f5VLTMI61O9EctGqcukdK22utnBdXIhXl2UWoWJJdZ73YjsM1l92LhJN82msJDPhdhg2jQ7CnQ@SY82MtmkqdzlEleG7GMTQoYS2td8lSkNorfly542y86vW4scTDkSnFRlo9pCbU0SI/XiysxctZ@vEol@s3sxgoIng7uBIDd9mV5XvJGUMnV3e9Ua5auTFjO8ub2OV5sXvsQybJw/C9rgnE8uGssKy4pSsj8tTuZhvSQkzhNXFUG5nJdrTUnsx@qhG@VcXVI5NT5g0xI3m85UxreIZhL5vpRpllUj1xQu4qJW5Rlm3r6zKu3bxFXonL1h6@MZGzKvZwwrdVR50Sl3OqEelZmaV3q7zk3zvgsr3akPa8K5wpTbteJSW5TyIbOZLmelq8lsoZcWshG@E0rnWaUqyByYJdFYv2E0R8vMtEu1pXkpm0nE70IXIEGmqSRnnQgvCqbenw@Z0vXkQpkPJ6OW4RvPmZrvrjOPJgetgckIpVKjXJzljah2aQ5VKhYTQhdtQ4@btefxopi1coNWU4lkk61@t3LRYa4b0lXyJlu/i4vRKlN8FpPteowVStG2wHA1bTy1YEQS@iOqtGB7hqCIBh@fVJ6j@cnE11tMJ5ZPv4ufXyXa/VGWmwq8L5zuas/8vHWpsHI5LvbNSns2vS20wUJUW9OmShXumnr4Sr6Q6hetyvWIq6ZrS4vJJNvCbaTfMThJlaa1sBW9LIr9uCDl8nejYe6i@FxkO9IzO@MU4@YmXLjgqLjky1haT2FaN/qNugzxYrpTSVzPesvseFCWxItiKGd0arFe/YpX8jCMys8lVm8Vzkt3va4yYCRNrdRrLEvdxUL59m3tmZv2bqrLhja/MPqX6aoSvpWKqla9bXG5G4MpxzOFm@ywdpddJGJVQ@mKjX6ioY5952FN4NNqKUbFxamYabWZpiiHufh82eVHIsPdtUejxAWzjJlLJq2as2Giv0x2z8dc@66snTcWI@Z8PL@rZm65iejjuKqgUzfWsho9P2/7rhbnzWJfaRYlgeHHi6F5kZmIl7PuTSztS@hsw5fvtQbzUrWvt/NMvNtNcPVwuB2xnnvVhXlTplq50kU4nltYcyk/mpTniQs9Hasv5s2bSGR0N5xXEvVYLTrnptoon9EL/Sij3Zpxdd646BcyYl66lszrZVcYU7HlpFwsJPK@qMh3qp07Vsozz/WeYg36UuPqNlyPMUL0olKd3d3l0sw4Lg3zReUcxsQZfz1f1IedUfemYoZlSqt0fMXYMras392Ue2q1fXk96M768XjVuGgNk5NlR6/JNZ@@bBa72nmuOlZyy1sQuFgtGR02lXyzLd/mamyFsmLt9AxscC5Tkhd9phhlrySVvZyPz5O343Zs1Bm1stNaZz4axurxqDYRl3Gr/RydiM1453JcZ4RuZzbwhc4prb5c3OZvIkapPNNLVlUTr9hEqHQ3ao7zk6ZvnL0qdK1sm9W7oXZpNvFlo2AVJK5byVC5ezXMFEfnN@bFTShJNQryYpIYnsfOfVUYTCZDs5JoKSFlyrQZpTWbiqMxy5dzfMuYd5uFUq/cCyUY3SfHZ9ZV7PmyU73jLT2iMpS5iPVmvO8iDxZETu5E676WpbNjmIuwt9PwldoPh0z1tl4XrKwWHzXDSTFSMFqq1pprw1ZIvjmPj2aCfDWkMuKyF1GatXavPF/OeslRpMfXp8104VZth7OqPpibBhdLXoVa/HN1bIQrll4tNYWMejPmeWnmmyuZ3LVRn1K9fjndaxeeJ9K0FamkI@nFbY@NTO6mQ05d3uY7oWG1mx5Is1o7sqzNwpneOafWxrI@NkIM22ip@VFi3rwQr6jLZV5cDBI3mWor0rwaJkdhpT@qV9nFqCJLwt2dOeGKnX7phusVo63MTXJ0IZlpMd5MSpdDZl7uVu5i2Z4YYSnfoDhmQtmSEL7M3/qsS0GJPstLrmwtk5K6KDflbr0/Teul3rA5KWcumAwXmp7PK@PwRY0JT/jMOJG7MjqGQon5aHrerFzHzMFd2mpFtGpomtDvqnL/NtSrDnhhzMYSoIOve927RTNdy8xKnfJF3Uyr/aXoM2ZX6nmxUMio1IXULj@bz7wmTdKRZqXUuXm@SRv9RrRrmUVu/iwyi4VaucwKwqKTLpqjcuuyrhbj7LiXuY7fDHoltalV5fAVJSTjo9s4o9aFywkrRqrpSOG5dS48F6exmjZSLaGRv@Oscg2UXTHarOid2XiZHbDSPBzJ35qVfk@/g946XFKhyUWt06tJQ3U@q11aravwuM6NWjNlFFN53RfJJysVnuuHcRIWvdXUsaZc9a3benl6ZTDMYBmbiPq5eCVTpZDeTxdrscsQf37eySWb3Pi5JIYS15FJehaq1K59alTUc8X@WGGzo9pQvJFhytCOVYeXbL0sN/t3k@xtclGnlp2ulFQv2zPtKjua5UbTYaM5D8P0qtEqmWa9dmv1itNQ9zKudCuDXiNXyN4IWZ434xU1m6@M9EmrO55dRKLUsBC@HV7HL@V@bBQviovO1URPVi@XxezgIuLrqJcJq8NbynNFGT6Xu5bVfY7LrfrNJdPOxAWVfV7ErdtBmzGpi8Q4fx4R48vigIs31fF0MulVaqpWXFRvroHN8VC4cd5l0nr7pmq1eheicHvRBEv/UhOL9dtLvX5@e9Gb9FRKCYP4Zhnj6rxkFm5zoztuVqwtujLnG1WuZpVoPColu75pdFweTHLRaDs@vixPCzndiM2vQev3q4tqSayVrylufN3Jj3yXEscljOtlaxqppcXbWPd6Js0i0Vx6rg4SiSY7v7k8F24SXb04Gzcvuf4NM7tLjswx3@RraUGTKlTmWQ8vcnMrz0bzV7GL2xtxGJv18pNQMT2rt4sxK1mW2u3I86w2G4nlAic15tNZqFqo3FhqJDpv3dyNrqAVopTQn9/k4@J1ROyx8vIuaxS0rtrk0yxzyYRmzdaNT@urz2XRN6qGCmE9lmfnVR5mxneZyWUv1m0OlfZ55iI5oHoRIe9rmLHiXez59vlaNm6HvvgYVE5Cqk1vrsEk6VrNRmR@IyU73LKVTbT5bmHJ5a@YdOTiYpIshkKXpWSpQ5n16Bik5XkWur3MKaGbaqsRmfhy5dy8N6jfNWvZ2XXirsONq@369BInY2GGnUmVYa25KBfmTVmM5Ue1vJShfMWbmVlJ6lIt18obTLUnFSLD0cV54VycXAmTeV71sf1iczF9nozFxOW1wouGWqhZg7QQ7iRG4blQ1NPPVy1qccHnL7lsopUwRrJwOSw3zaE5beuSnI48R@c@qzasylfRXK1xqw6bg3LZELLXobgp5kb1ceyuOZx3p2K@d0lJVnIqKPPzcsxSM4uCfNu8vrns1dmFUE1clgvGnO0yhec6O7WYZqJebfS7ZUMuDWHg9HWampZQQKVYA@2G4vVBkZ210le9RN/MnrOJ0uW80pTLPvYmXxvmQubU8DGDcSWUW2r5y7A0i/drN1dj1shOewPfVTXO3A0z2qxMRa1euM2bo2RN4jqdFqPna0vTvE40u76rG4URa6G7eOZiyTW6Yb03GXQSnfH59LnTuX7utuoX0Jy3PjFWv36m@jdXF2ZcSgpcr5nJltLaVGcvjXFNioxLWqcZ6ki@zjxXnD2HrtjCsNjlyuXBcpkRLo22msiNu9dZfjFsJlpUOF9he3dhUb9s5p47hcFkKGRLcyF8q12YvttIeT45NxLxGBdJTnkz3BqPW75EWpF98fBgMQhl8tNYjukZtTaVr/iybU2DXlC7i/Flxoz0yoplNuONej5ZyxayF6Wr/K1UStaL/O2tr3NTzObTjdjl1WAUuepwZobJXA@G9RA1LGVHPcayEhO5LhfM/LmRmw/uRjfjSXcWn5bMzlK94idyf8xJvD5ql9R4LH3Teo5W2HD@msnfLRU1FI/Ok1RPkHqXjFIb3bYTcv6C6SgDmEDnQP5Ht9cTQ5AMc5BsQ82vl2o826z0W8aFMqgChUp3ogvSOCmPBmL4jqox9UQh3lauJKHSqY3jna5827gMx6XJHOavndzySsox0OrNTn0wYW9jeTBdI5HnYnswvpmWW2Ytmms1StUI1Xqu5SSumC@VWndWjytX2H5hajXjiYs8J4wzo3J@kelmirOC0Gxf@Ia@UKMnTAuttJJv9Xhzvrhjk6yRloZUbBi7zkg5zppFW5IRyV4OKmFeKWrzymVCH9eql6HMZf5G0kYGm7lJrz6x1iI5lqOLvpROn7eKnWyfSt9kc8NQSzKFmuqbFQlYpqDwf/jVR4WIhqESMGqqyT2avCrXOebi5CsHT5CTJ/Dx9p1zJ9DZZ/sgAcl5vhpogXL8riY@IXxsF0L2NoN4PDluLZ683lsMcKvjBMgFz/Ggj8iR5NLORqjLwMxrMj7K6tcIIDueZAcF98HI48k/mMfwBRr8K5TAJvJEnYfwxvtN2ghH8JwPPPGPfTzZ2vL0cNvUIIHQZLwqAT/9rh/wVIUfISPZAs5XCt592/rsyU5@IM7UVXLSiCsQdJGszqkYiGkXhd2aGL8@m4EiB7KsNta@8sIVnuESbCxJzvegVb/lH98nH/1HQspFi5bMq2NzYsx6o742mEq0QuvD7lxYLJ9pOhqhw1BW6Efah2VysRRDjsqMw2@CTrLO8Uzk84kc/IvHVJFz@PBcZzdNB9ZHPH2kvSTgx59j18kbKaWPxisptA/5GN/HHlNqij0Z36uPJ6rP57V8KcvH@TwY8SPnPdEnjifivfVIntpnjujr1aP1eBw5@v5qEl3VVGGguU2avMhy@5kTchjXqgONeX27P01FwdKM7RgJ5Ykf73TEt1G4S8y/yilrKzhroYu4dbc@lUDBN/ziz4dJLHLyNh1r@OEDHqFx4vhObFfgC6VPuoosHFMfCD9xCxwfpz8@dg6FEWiU2w8fSJxsR9q00LLpweSTVaqg6Qsns2yDPK3qcrqF8syDe6te//dArqC6IJNP@PIYA8BsEJu9O@A0oCZbo16bKgyXRHW9D4rn@HhP8JQT@uMqbXXiD8Kj3JBzd54sWian9MDllHZAyRkYtNc5cYLE3sv40BtxJThz20kfhpOxTvafgza9DkfwfXdPOi8b65xBc4Iv4PTQHDJDXhGNLYCBFzwPbcpb4nbTrNoCHd/Iw1dYH8RXJa83AIIF3jAWqBvx4QPE19NIng/2CxU9tKXZjpU2GU5eUg2v09TAODzI1q27j2niB3cCUWRL9GQrdQipWNd3kseQPOatwTvJA8Q9Md9LNiAZX7P4TrIMyfYzkfvTNUi3d/rfAbDQyxPE9cnSnixeVjz2gR54FMiLrbA9tM@3YuxaBGi7Yez22M1PO0ej0B/t1rGFbUe8oH8SsbIBUKQ9TufB@420kFQ859djy8VWmTZP6C/0NwtznCOBxU@kJFC7WL73aAc/vUUA9D9QpfTb9FXhdmuvK7ojP0EYdvrY2sCsMP3LL1@jzBHEXfnjHlfSZ7cQ@uFu1dDm1gaP/Ra4TbvamZZOpv15nKNjtrXbykdiU49VpwxtVIjdtzb9WpLVHpQBiD9uR6PLk5f@tIm5Nx/p47X22PDR7hbf5mPojfSgRxTpkX66uwkK389VHuUecvIwInc3ygLPCeNP3rDTXEMHdqHPAHrNzVdyJuzIjNNLf21lv682B0Af6dSENye2ohXANDxzCNxDHm@367ZOsJEduo/teHy7nbyLTH4HmX2e3hMgsE6BBhzZVmp8NSbKatB@JhX0PBuK@ImLuQ3ysmHTSll9D5/@GToXMs4Zsif4wp9dlUTvYc0b8HW9kV9nr7vcq@rZmn5/5e7th5rdn9xII/1WnojUfYJR8phm6fXBTSf0y7f10D@OM182zbdj75ie93XFqtFXkvg9IvjyDqO/KWS7VQg90jscn5CXyuvfHJLIIYT7B6WNa/3TKmbldmn37XctMKTqZDcdabYRrhLAUN7O5XdsrrON6nROX3yyVsaNf2OF4Xv2bKkAk/2E2lbnOJ0rkMF7O3Z9dBThyHYKPsmOFqaxokyWVrYtmMGrfEHhCZvZZjLyE/p0X9N6npXB5BgMBMPqhA4A8tvHWa3NKtu83BQPxTlGL913TvlYjbsnEPPRiSLjCkSg8enIJhJx1Cfd5gS7zZZ9I5vkNZAkHUcjKGr19AE6K9rahz5@HY/QaxPow95MK42PZ5KRkysdPU9G4h314MryKjqGYnPYU@tTF8avGwJhzmCivTnfkrTBy55VBvsMT@d0yy/bUxf5RA6iTbxu9JUXpPdkTc3pqQuLWQv8yx8OPjIT02C6ssqI6hSM6u6COqBF1X770TG@IjuQQEdhfMO1o02IXzZxQgQxgZbC0oKqOPM4b8HGU0RdXso@k444LXIUHuJL/MYVcdoDq98@sUXXzDn5XcBkgQ1OdEsjKU5B5Ow6@hf5l815qix5isiZMTjknBI8GxgPPl9gxy5sX8kAZxtIHJ5Q7N1CcY85icJ1Pbhc2H5IqONPev9ImUGRFwZIBMreL/Z0CpqLSPILZa6aHs9aQ1bgwysQVOxTJnTiO4pFEOvEXJB7qD7ecxiwY4iLK8q9M0@hiEMwpiiapqOQoyso5j8FBtiM/1Bv5PK1WtB5r4XtsY5e7rYfMz4iSA6sc95g77jxorc6HhdoN8oHrCzitstLbZAT/Ut4hMU6bMKuMEN22rzC8wjtGgQ4cvemGmt4rw1OWEIed3LuTOQl65zqoYMdhbzbZPNsZQussq2At1jx4Zvc4AUBD4K4FscaUJwVFQWItnnxYcMODCJHVuX71uWb91jm45p4Oz3wJj2wkx60022iNlBBYWBsgI63gVwHXzZwL7RrA@Z/U1aKhkoXy@R0qaBmbNF98jVYMwiTNHkDfLZuSlsq1wmnOwmBrZSf9rS@nfJxJ89awNfp93a6I98hp@XXVO7Aft4tH6@U00AiOYPBeWTxlZQGVVn5/4u7sua2cST8PPwVsFL2iAmtw@PsTI1jT2iJslgliRqSsq3aSblkibZZ0eHSEUm1k9@@218D4CErTrb2YV8kEkdfQAMNgOj@Q24/Jjk8wgq4VZLV0d7c7aRSqg0RNZwc0zCBEPNQ24vzFMq7qh5xWGcKFx8@FkpqS@qP4i4ZMiDTC8XaoyMZKTHOdyy4Dc8khIezDzIgGCY6mtCae6Erb1XlbQYsSh1otIb2FJpXcGJtV8XP8Vn33/jRyp4nTpd7sz/zJ0n5RjIvb1rkBcSD7kFhv5jyo8lyvopkomLqlVkkxb3dhbh/kOjMsAIdPmGkSHBG8j7Iw2w1HR0k40R2oNAjxQu5JzlK0mmBqu6@32pCZH41/l1@a1wNJmQVjqONsGFTD9ihvZG7bLOMFssF6UBEDM7FYvX8PI6VXzex5uscks/qyXtcRkghZoyGkuHigqgsb@FJXY6hSiXhAfIa9wzTjMXq8VHGGxcIaEpD60NMIJclw55uZSh0uEE7kVdeIrGCH1cMwGNa9mWIkC0ntScJGl8y9MUiyeqD1O/pkkwgYnzGPg/havV3w/hzFQ8/167ESaXya7XySzUjMr1VXSn9csoR1bWJpDNOKtVK5X311DBqs@etvNpYHJqAdXoMgJZoYaK/pr4ZfUHAUcOmGYMLLsj0X0TzL9GoZBh@NOI94PsVSwRdebWIpBdl9vOKFLKt4O@ezN3JwhK07HrC8IJ/zM/Sd@2QHWtYBu4QPUfzSbyUN41mX@IRBKjvTT3MxuPZmjeicWVJygOVJtGShPLWFHmS2C@tooVtF3YXS9IYqLjog/vZF/YjrcRAdmoM9/t8AciAE0VAyCKTQZUzlBC@4XgQT9Cd9hAAL0upBDQBxNpoNYxepcFgIv5LGnTA99FsuIJn3oFumTKNfjPWFVL3aB7T6JsKmFuFq2VopwYOm24gAq8R3ti@I@i563vXbt2pi8u@CJuOqHndPod@Ek2vRaNLIOxOnVI7oe9e9kKPEgp2QDULnGHYnb5wbru@EwTC84Xb7rZcgkbgfbsTuk5gCbdTa/Vosr6yBEEQHS8ULbfthlQs9CzGqqsZaT3hNUTb8WtNerUv3ZYb9hljww07QNYgbLbo2n7o1not2xfdnt/1AkeAMaPuBrWW7badegnxozqecK6dTiiCpt1q7TDq3XQcH8TnuLx0iEr7suUwJuaz7vpOLQRD6VONhEcEtiwRdJ2aiwfn1iF2bL9vKaCB82ePClGmqNtt@4qYM4rfkQq1S63nO20QTZIIepdB6Ia90BFXnldnWQeOf@3WnOBMGC0vYIH1AscSCMbHqAkGSYvy6fmyF7gsN7cT0pzR64au1zGpkW9IMESlTVXrLGCvI7klIXl@H1AhB24AS9w0HUr3IVOWlg0pBCS1WpgtRghJiGGWTdFxrlruldOpOcj2AObGDRyTGswNUIBgAu@NTUh7zDXaieiSj9RZDd1zLW5O4TaEXb92QbkqTT0gcFVvYbHVmkrmpMtlY@@R26sHeC9P@dRWyOtO4mte3SGLTwZYKaTpPZp0fssf3uXyaKJJMulVnYLyXHU3iu5Xj3fx9GGGpXlSTZ5gTxaPFkIEmQiF@JfxSixWdVDOFd68ubu7tu9onRvc3ZnWj9TMkfG9GsoL62ulTMXjeDYY8TI/t7eUFdTFkfL1bknHy9m9lqNk88EU5fIoUtVweRGA9TaRCkpAwEYYGflW42AqMij5iDm/V8QRM3Y3i/Tx5mxBP9O/0xc5N2QSaHCW3y2Uy1jDMhmIfCIS@gkJBwVRkUH4O4D4gVGWFlH0@bFYyaLDkl9tUJm6Dpdd0jLwsWh@p/p99LhT/Xi3PhOLu6ZsrGh38NpNu4xEjzclMqHapTRnzopya4//TE0NIyKj0JSo@CKr@vqkeCSrw7@o3Cs0zxJX4hwOpG3fujdYzFVOTs920ptJutQt3DpHbBua7/7J9T7xX/OTLEAKFmP5RSKJt/JItVzO1CGrjO3JpDB81T@h0Doe0ZyKqfop4mkdHvKlu@BsfZqM5/EmSz0Nw1e@3b7sNRo0coLa09/e//qPM0N53J8vby353wcehElk6ZIVvY7JTOOsjJbUyO5pvAiWk4nug9ZDQUQd1I3GiQMyaRPPmdJGkPE15DYQ2F0gwsAUQTYKCBIwLwjcz48ODN1f92qm6gDFHKsmuJkMNmzhD8hU4j4wlF4yx1tutQ1@ADtRf63iCUOqA6kuFk2el1vqubS44HGv0NAOB3htw9eKUaRU0P34eaC/QZKCwZjJXhhwB5/fVN/OtCLZtWho6Cs3O9ckIg52qdBBWjjkEqHozhZag2ViTCm3qr/RY18FB0IWQj3Yy4DE2EhqHuvgPXLPWSmGgvzp4pya6OgowfRBYCPVVETJ/f986JisNjAp8oMGsQNYf3mUyDnJ4U3ojz@b4l@yp8KrN@CcqR6r3qnn7mNHQTnTLtHVu44gIySsNKAMJ60THIYu0tdFEnHmxPQ/yYPh/x9lsgf@B1pwEvRUWjwOx9NV9IOSZKhSVrR6ZaHEa/3FWOYztVSa2aR@CuZrtmGeEsbUZ3gbebBEIlCts9UJfRlSrLhHAOjk2NfI6i8c@LISPw1o5fSRdfcnedI/nw4nz0UdkEtPFS/gfrLY5rL0J3J4MeURfkVk0LUQX@Uj@3nkMQMLLhrF7rficFGQMN5VecwB0@W3vOmRaDl3TYihqjU87U4VpVpa@TfqC6N0lhnp3K9kin472FdyHIKYQrkBX5@A6AGEv33KMqzERjgvQOhevuHphXf5hZrFEbGRhkCel0XI7jkWgwdeM2MqUr404LQDKAHncKRiNt1HyzWmi7GEzj5EUmiieMhuTIBE7UUmZoQefM0SSZ0n2XVCPW9Tor8m1Pemn6cIuBvJLS5dopSLAJV1wVoS7QEHgxr/GN@FFPk7iPUij9@dsl@VoTyvxNYcr9wJC1b6h4tUImRxrmFd0jyUSmkw/IzEgu6j8fo43tAf4zpWnOuYRrRm4Ih1@4z@r99cEKCv7HwDKwp/TZNNpN/lRHZ@qM0XPEndTZ76eFL7zOfEFBFHKfhgVplBIBl2Ez7SfKltTN9/AA)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Boolfuck (130) [local](http://samuelhughes.com/boof/)

### Explanation

Boolfuck is a brainfuck derivative similar to brainbool, so similar in fact the only difference is how they do I/O and that the tape for boolfuck is also left infinite. The difference between the I/O is whereas brainbool only operates with '0' and '1'; Boolfuck operates with the bits that make up bytes sending the least significant bit first. Also Boolfuck uses `;` as output instead of `.`.

Because of this similarity I use the same loop for Boolfuck as Wheat Wizard created for brainbool in answer 100.

The loop now looks like this:

```
[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]
```

Because the number of `+` is odd it is equivalent to the one `+` that was there before to brainbool. The `<>` in the middle was so that the minimal 2D answer remains unaffected.

#### Funges

Because the top line contained `;` which is the Boolfuck output command I had to remove or hide them. My first few attempts were to hide them with `[]` but none were successful. So I tried removing them, which after realigning pyramid scheme and ><> revealed only Befunge-98 and Trefunge to be broken.

I realised rather than skipping through the top line I can try to go around it. So I used the Funges' wrapping behaviour and the `^` that is part of the Pyramid Scheme pyrimid to wrap to the bottom. To check that I had wrapped correctly I set up a quick test  that skipped over the bottom line with a pair of `;` and then used a `v` to wrap back around to the top in the same column the `v` in the top line is in. This worked successfully for Befunge-98 but Trefunge was not working.

After a while I had realised what was going on: The bottom of the polyglot is at the z=1 level in Trefunge and so Trefunge  was wrapping to just before the form feed. I took this opportunity to move the form feed to after the Trefunge code and the Trefunge code now flows right to left like this

```
 @,-1,:*b5<>␌
```

The hard part was now getting the Befunge-98 to work. Both `#` and `;` where causing trouble when I was using them to try to skip the parts of the bottom line dangerous to Befunge; The `#` caused trouble for Algol and the `;` was trouble for Boolfuck. After an unsuccessful attempt to hide the `;` in a loop I decided the best thing to do would be to put the Befunge-98 code at the end of the polyglot. My first attempt at doing this was right mixed in with the Paintfuck but the @ sign necessary to end Befunge caused Gammaplex to fail. I then realised that I could route the Befunge-98 through the -`-` in the wise and the `2` in the `27.say` to put the code just before the Gammaplex. So the Befunge-98 main code is now

```
@,,1'1'<>
```

on the 4th last line. This code turns left then pushes the character value of `1` twice before printing it twice then exiting.

With Befunge-98 and Trefunge no longer traversing the old Befunge code I was able to simplify it somewhat. It now looks like this

```
>77*,68*,@'1    #
```

Multiply 7 with 7 to get 49; print; multiply 6 with 8 to get 48; print; end;
There are still some leftovers from the Befunge-98 but these were required to keep other languages working: `'` for shove, `1` for whirl, and `#` for Del|m|t.
I replaced the characters I removed with spaces as I was having trouble moving the Pyramid scheme pyramid leftward due to Del|m|it.

#### Incident, Prelude

I added a space before the parenthesis that is the arguments to the main method for Objeck to detokenise `ain(`. I shifted one of the parenthesis in the case statement for the shell scripts to unalign a parenthesis that moved from the `<>` added to the bottom line.

Answer (score 6):

## 133. [PATH](http://esolangs.org/wiki/PATH), <s>5309</s> 5301 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxx  h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRc
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l@O6O4/111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><
>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPQs""o<>-}
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"1
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pRcxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._ #]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002253 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5420 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKciD4vBDzB36pRWlvkuIFAO/UbS1eJUoUSfGq69YGQYAECQIUAF7X1gnPi7vt6ZjpcXscbnePT9vRE@GImaeemIieaEdMxPRrf8X5gTl/cCazAN4kaq21bVMiUajKysrKysrKqkoU2oLZ@8Mf9vBDKro676q6RSzJtEjHUCaSESTpOfksKGY0FGYYhEoZ3fFQ0izzkNkjPCGKJioduCeWPpA0ZSEZEB8iZGToXUMYEqsnWEQyRWEkmUQfW6OxRXR5d7YwIbmh3lcCmHOoaF0AsyRjZEgWTY8Q0tBUYdjuCK9Soq8KHBmQbpKspP4y/MUioj4cClrHBMgYIdlyOldMvcIQJ@RKN0wJ8YiSaeoYmSBklpPEV6BJABUMRS@mSmevkniOnAHpwkiVZkRom5YhiJaiazbvKobeGYtYL6snQU7khayoksmIQPMpGTktEMQA2SOGJHRsMEbWDYJZyHCgEoWIoxFpq0IvKBJVAdg8lyASso4sIF3tmWQ2GgIGUx9KmySaRJOkDjFHkqjIikhLJ9LMkjQTqDSDRBEHZKqoKulIKmRYkyT6ARkZmxtRNgFBpqMzBD7i6FUFVnf7EsBo0pIJ0gi4h0zQkdnAkSUvpoYwGgGRwMgaEG4pQ5AZxXKbRBJMBaUSspiS1qH8G63kVSeCtllLMlEEIgC9Y4PiNiUDGyFI8ZKeZEiAUlhJjGdqKBawANmbIhVJMEjdkCTvtuxuFQmF6ViChRUJ0uY7Pnbnynk3NKOdIyiMLGbPCNevLxiBBE/I/tMRfE9criMmV8qSL/sPGLZFFZp6ZHgELzn5DTHZhwcJvjO@zXaNFwawMsAVlbD6yGKFwAgIDFhAICtgEEOBSSg4UjcKJsev2mJDuGyoDrQGKWik6ac1E8eGgd1xzVRhAJVWda0L/ITKGmMN@aGRGAdNIOrQm/xEmgDXdM1uI31KOVzvKdBoJjbJRgewlQplKKgVkD2Ho8tyTV0dUzjIaVoogMAVyIoYCzJpEllQVMwC6YjKptqQzLFqYZ6x1sGWB6UhdYJkSYaodxBoqE@gOAGQ0gjoS8ONHkiJAmBoCJ1WFZN@96//XafbBTwpUdSNjiOuTdLRRar@BEos6BSCAqtrgkrJAjg/lm5nhwImgqp0BAuL1@ZOEZQIWupUH6sdokOBxlSBrtUTJtAdZVkSLckWcltj@slQGNh6Q7ElFyo@FNrQsLQAWjatdoB8zkAriRKzR2UmMBxbcoIERjniNtmfPJ8OPZ8@PkhAnDfoPdhn2e4RCFzwgEbBnftrktNMbWg0UC6WYOpKhxnNrZ6uhUhAJC7xRB9Jmse9hcPtdxtttzeI@szjPVJOxKCsaB2PG2Q8DeW6vUfiiXivHD4evcq9WSJgmSIW7K2SR/S6GNA4tE9M2KGgaMHRnDQDTmgjTTefkOOYHNyIRr68jpvYEXt0wECx1FE@QA0FTVWSRh4uyHtRSyDczmpjwq6KvsLhVPhQefS599y@zapTDFDTrYpiX60rOmotddQbg44GpmjmCLS3gaIrCiA8JipxC0ZtP2lTsaaaHxQLVYlTyW1IpA16dClGtEfaPQ7zB1BPOhjWPWgJt92hpc5GfwZdAF3aMt8oZVWfQsGUNhy@QINoWLjQhSaCzHaFUnaF7BJpzHbVBhroFcTWlkgi0FagL2CvA9XuiP5GHQE8HLJhAJvdVzZU0FCYAxbRHhLX/YYoMnSpIWgJY05ECVUP6CDJHlewkDHthibYK2i5cIFQNLrd1d70NMtgU4E70NUL9qsdCiuf2rISYACSpSlRBa07FrpoMmmQRRBFaWQ5@gpqYlqgkV4POzQy4IyhQbPH7H9@XTYdS5zRdaMM1PV26zkjooBKxjGaAiroVCI4Zh/pKAZoJ3X@unQAmLwq3PUzgmwR8LPrHRKWhgAImTSTxLEFyg0EedpTxB7ILlKn2erRHoteFw9Rm6WDgg/Iq6KRGP70xxATZFdRSMa7KALYom/xwBiLqE63Imjjb0Z8HbNgDncg1lckwniwERtkhSDI3jdwDnVN34EUGLlCiyDbKXY7gEFWQ2MQxq@l9UU768pCXDURtBloD@j5IH89yxqZhzBcKFZv3A6CpLB1Y16wyhoKC2sZc8XS7XBb1dugnk3on@yyBFYct5XZqwrRuFUb9k1mAnaYbJITGMCfxyB1HrdsguKk8RkE3khyUQVOUdi/LgCkQEFglEc2qUrOg1KpzTXR4wrSrhSETufyExd2XJcXAphrxZeMPkQtRFrUPkCDL22A5pJBWzm6n6p@YeeItxoDqHnndgf7uqJ5vrg/fvzoPnSfgob/@PEThI4x9AlDPgh9oqEADSFcEEM0h5@GMPWe5sC4R/fL/RLzzPuIzTbD0WmhjDzC/eFh@NEv3PPONYRXL6g60GwAHcAL4HF7T04w6PW6TqdQ0WBbtmtftTnbodJQlbQuI81GumGRUjmbe6qk6ucnLnZsGqyqtFkNxtenIfRgmMu4duSHSckyOwSrum6d0AbDeAqdByBnssZY@hj6PMw/lKFiFejsR9VQsNeNtkzNQLlrBBVFshhnNFrLOk6E1m0D9aDwhc05kWzow5WGMxlJ7OnEtR92oS2/NR/FYd9JjWDq2JmNbsTHMX6IM8mgyHRFkQR0@3YV6QAmEBBnl0GYzDFdnw8h6WxzFelAJilKnHEGjfYy8gvPvWD8arq5MY5sYtyV/n4mypsd82On0BiW2NHbkjqLRQKSKget2SKIaiEWYewLCXTeg9iRl5ktdmVgLOjjgZn8KkEwGJvCOoxVRZiakKJi0uWEzeZkVh3hgXHZHTW8PQq51imhtcm42851bWKhQguCMNBRLa5DT2DURbdQwDT9bU5ZMXv0Zwv0DUVvU2huc9iW6c8OgEPHdgLRx4k8suQCp4Fovuk6TPqnFIyOAhQZsErRBLZKLzge7KJne2TbIqYtyWOYGrJtRcPwN8ACyQSFlNtt5T1Q4AuSvrzuADPG7V1sA@HqvTF@yBbjrbFhqVLHuf63P@5AA7xtnp4whymNOFgFnoBv2FQB@d3WcrLiDf3Z3bIUpj9WFYGygYa@hVIUcNopqKvAbtSoekkg0BMMaNz5snFBOPEHhtGvyJlNuSGp4460vO4uhLJ428Syc2vKkNYIrmgv0vHyneyvDEQ7P07bDVUXOhSLvZyiSOvWtttFmgldqBy7oZFAE34HnUs7jqzXT8Bgscb2Ly6ZfKtdlRF@v9ZfHUguKrR5CSabQlt5h4tIROw9uba7CxoYAVkVBnbwCYO7q2pXxlC6XTCsnOt7YGBFw0RnJIgSO6WXd1WMNjZHdlNg6Cv4DNX@fQ9kub67CrwHCNVU6c@vETsqCCL0DSQVlywDGyxSXjFVFdpzNMJ6v15@sEA6joJ6ORF9Pi6MQ@pqjrteHB2N3s@PNgDNn0zuzm2vo1IEoi7LkvStPgvjjjIU1ECosxF8VwUvjdZ1aAdoX5gIYM6qggkCYjlslibQLPTna0KLQ4k4VgVjHfqKyK7JWS5lvDcbXucZKaKuKo5kLm/e04Wv5xFrNLhSTn/WWfHuLX87YLrjMB1YhXZ3aF20cEb6jhx9h3qyJ4M43d4QjKD@Hu9EfYrfd3tvT59I9u/uIWuxk6rvUD8BlUoGTAffZu@I3xJXXNqkP7u5ONhJlSWqO@MPyZWuGz1JM0koyKGBo9H1eBiwVdWendYL5fdl2lRU3SQ1@vs1XoDJb5r2725p3mSbImgBsWf3sVV4d7adRNHhjaTo7zuNK6hdXY0luqwAP@9KwNiQUcs71@/VcCsNxfPf1FArc0fXeOf6rmofwP@3hIOutBq4ALER/IoVtUudORPX9ysIMwJcVdxduTyXoDmDrD1Pe68BDLE3FebL6z9i9HiPu8vRYzSnxjJYc5ghmYCAZdgG9D@mtMjXS@t8n456gzb@rUpsNO5AlUBj0983TUpCHP8rc/Ac9/0aS1bH0ljaqUHK7b4EYvM13fH9RHFONfadlQ0WmIebsCuohTMV/C6qcTzHu68qHEFVoJN/05rZqWpGYGGPcOpcgUAFA28zdrXxaKtxN3hXHWvVr3OuN1r2bL2zRSSm/FqNlPi2zbRlhpsS/e5WIIfoXgATXn0INoT2He3vIKWLQPbvFmIas8bcV3A9yvgq3kOyWqkE@xXsEWhVZWAGcFHr@xRP6L2ZOgVOJmEupknWHH/f4/YuRdrWdfXXtA7o046CZhoYn@iN8K1WemP7OIvWZL0mYeL6Rlt@bzXCHmucaSNwD6fI7zZ0Bapk0cHhe1r5zSrfV0atjTW/b80JYcSmSz6mIS7D79Fbxc7NBxPB@FcJXq6HscvA15Alg@HvsY9GS6OXLqniMqy98Lp2p9h7pX9Gc@CU0gmYYk8aSvT2Kxa/0OmPzeXlXaCZjt8dyUGWLoq@k2@kQIfX8HdrkXfDJLJ0TTJZSzC6Es5VVEkAa9SOfU/JLtdadzK3MBS6Uv6bkrVecMDtTNFQtoK7lx4O7R0GEbJ9Q43Y00BdG0hzc3ndbSzPRWjP8fCr2HZ1chHXNb/Zq4PszvXlb9h8Wk/vaT2pZ9Cesbp7r2@ARFq2R9XXKgH09wRzgPu3jkIaWUUSeCYbs72euclnVVfV7@EzqkZbUer67sXXHHpQdSDrr8I7F9qQ4Fx2a7FU/fxreJytFuqas9q9Nf2OTxHEKYbjQWKu3LT2CppoSHQvd7m3R/Zwh3k8hKm7pRtBQuE8HsHn83oZOxPO/roagC2hqKMM7p7bPjgmgTm5RWEVmdzfk/0vs0PukH8hJ8R16CKPjzZWuo@bm42oh0vVznq/Lzye7LsDAfe@@0E7JJybgkoqGOM7QYUtOFmhF5vOddWJJgzphj2GlzU9sr0CYI6Mjjc9QeuoEmnAaEJXDnTD3tu2HSjquFj8X/@@4/gjgfowyVAxwfjqauhDpw@lnj79ZJfrlJ4ajQT0Z0Ic0x6uhmLpgUyKmFPFAnVJ3ZBgCt/I1xOOV4Pj5Qc3FVQaG1TYjYoDGfraWHaj2dR0dMkWC6fgVa5lpURdHQ81MlU6Vs8MwoRXEyXqNbHa54IQgmmWgfLa8ZMC6Ui4WNdBwqiyVnV9QDfwkJL/@ve2LwckKihCGF4WT125NkokOABRBwpR1MdA9RLJQjJ0B8SDTAaFMUY7CIRasuO9ROwJ1MkEJDGwdLHAYmw3i0yqRgI54kZXRNy4PVJkz36qeta85x5PfkOGrPTf/pj1fnH45vohEOdNl58sQY5eUK42kzlIXqe6iWt/5nKqhU5v1MdrJVSOB6sHw7S5li4TQ@ovR@VOmlKXCboTqaE@REc0zYT@AbdeitruNCf7nrE96AZqFomivyaMYwKEbA876nqE2/@YZX9GfiE9lJWASPgoB3c2Q1T0OBmepJdbLeHN3TA2K7XHdG14EgqGwie0OvtPJ8enNGRIHR0dwO5/epiFuMDDLJ57ZM0lcx4eZj9woRvgnm5Arh9Z7EC5UvbLfvCU@@UXE2bBLteL@8jeHYRevv@lUqjkavVUvVEDbr7Yld3L68ZQWGsKlIWRKojQfVTqWQdsMRTJ/Lb2WGmQ1R2AezxkXyDH6Hvr9a4SVqAOq10B174dXIHAwLiZ@xvZd@U3pY30twCOZpIV4mhRUqGC5MiM29zUoP6lbGG7YHcfg85ecgQ3fHeoQsojFzkBLgWAS9/JI/K2lnYLfqIR0IzfZtTXcexCAbxaQ7wFQCatysL62ul25XZW/uWfocYjGNf@qTWmOL5aY4T4Wo0BcJ2N5sinCsVGNbedCcRp7UYNJoeBXvAy7Vu2Q6YtXbrj/LfUTDDw9Gx/HkFd61aTTBRTaasSlTcZRwYwjWl3pFtEJmoXgoosSFKqCZq80wHV1J5bqNlApQepU4DtGRDQiGsPmBVcDbR@4mIQ1jx56wQGmmsKM0jxZzvzPoWjmE1mh9Pqg8T@7l//O9tR9cGC8J86YRnC/8oO/8Qig94629k0rliDbGkWKsSE4dKu@FCYbdQJRywcERVtLBFlCBycUIYguE3sur5rPJ77JvATGgGYiaoXtS0tTzIePegqdciyaGDgFDBIN5alGbQDKGvqOfU8RsdhGCDYWDQW4VkgMjBZIgwoNsLAyEbo9R6CrDETZXTyc1skx8fHxGWKgiqdxI5sRrL7wk9h188rQvcBlrFtkXsCeSDLOgeknTrZPPuCj/diVuxybt5NHo/AzLDbBUYqDw0AiBejNYcfLhgKdYdV0OiaNLOoOp8vbSwwcDTqASPZ7uNLRAFAZONG/9bXsrvesUQ/jg1pDm42g6uFYDUEO3TtEp37n8iD9aA9Om7OBATmP@wQJA3Cf7bD93klPam3Xree1z6zWBvyuabpuIedB2qJJ8SGwiwf8270FJeDCujFfvELoISeAD1LlJS@PjJTmVzholypvfEapZDu12Bu4j499j0Egv77x1XA/Urql0xN59naVTq/ZOUmVevFIIRYrwi9JnNXaa8pfaf0lr1d/LZsmvCmIJ77XsR0zhXI00XTt9jXqewGYMbeznpTqsf75eX@8fj0Qdt7U/wvuxzq94IHKFwQejCpO72b7NA5heUmeB2fdjKDS3@qkGv9uMjKW8y@X0e/7/e5enZq7fy53G5Hx8/QKduRJqw2VlUm@M5GPNQ9yNpFUc9Hm7AlvaBrlqTySOq6QJF5s6C3SQ1x6vL2MS/HAW7FpLI9PaWO7YIGMxNDEW1okypoexJLvbBhGlOw1jMfmE3hIgyd4M3pZAZUxWpzsKPQpQjBWHrmrVJq0lAJ1Jf0oOJYO3OCIkMnxR7UTVXaR8LJ/Yys3Mm@5ucZNEeqYnnQwXIWxEki1MbjxQrwx6qE/pnHyUfHGZQsfTZ91O2zMgZ@VfQRWU/Ms9IyVIW5GcmOATmIgUQuxkOAk@mlKuEoIZGSHoDMwEf3koh7KMXj1CE47ESh9GBPmnWULow0Hq8fVNIPPL92GBW8PphQu0EP26w6w13PTcb8KifXDY4J90JQ0TrSzIMPNBw@Incg3j1tTdxe1xsZoJ62jttt57XL7VJZCJbTa9fuqq8UQjK5UgTbfSeZDPZMBt39YF4BJdYsowhBGEM98lAYEc@Y@iybJEjorefBo/lNy/CSwCmOZ1OiEZ@PzkjgQhOChOaUaUhRcd3Og0/6eNgTaGeMNbUOXhbKiNzzweAjhGkhXrKPawoZMDdwNu5lwOCELIcULQzA8HeIFE1h7oUU2dd9WiyDCwIGQO1Mph2526MdEHhBa01OfyRrbbDugTZXk8lDpzW21WGSgFgc79AYgHaHmltanMBfx2cLuIZKDKAyMNVUQKF8vpQ0DfqrB2RmCL2TCGMQMsPrXz5m6l8/wURL2LNJPHecwIDQ7Sebcu4vqg72zD57ROe1Ry8w7v/8gAO/7Az9c/aP2CB79MWzr57MWTDGvKee/d4J7wsf@Hz72oFnX0Nz5McfcTr8sg/WzlPQFXTNACiwr3qPQJ7BOjrZ1472hWPPfuckdEBzwK3P5/0CGX5jssEv@8ILu/8jWBN@iDHs3unZN73YHbhgkH8B@rCH7LN@kJkvHhdx0YdEsfh9xedDGoL7T0jAb9iHmo@OKw81ls68jxwjl@0Ol2pk21ZZtcSbh15tBjrRhyuNHqXOvPZq/9MSePPBph1pu@yjP/xhj4/BJOpTLOzRP4XCHw/2yN5nF3vgMlxfHrIT970gh4LPj5VBpXLjffCARLr3MmUXH3GRnwg5YJk99oD7Jc6yP//8M1if5P40eBp89N4H3I/3ntlpPH7gjyUO/J/dvD2JhgkZz3s9oZCXJQ818hAXhANfJPRZO1IUZWR2OvDVe/iYHVhiJyglH@Dj4StudzTsrv2EbvafPn2EP/oPn9Ut/n6kMU40BXn7@eglnucZs3c6@@7PE3zLaRpssjwfetA@4CPPsY@fP0CdJR/9HB5@phMZ4oonXLr@GYAJ6e3xfJToezD0zSTSJrNZAD/Mnri3gCR@b07/njDM83WhLhD8b@Nf1cK/5gD/qmJVZPZ@c3Li@87PbBUKBp@WIWbv5@OfT/4JH2YPpiB7p6ePLy@@wH3wpyPf0RF@8R@67zJ4RD92CIp/9AV8x/fHx8HT09lp4PH0ntn7wuzNXpi9kAtk7eGA2TuZHVcpjffZU4faZ2dWXYTwceDxvlIEy7nuDx0H9kL5VMYfqjXSezzcRde3mBjG22oulS03ALpSzKVqubNCM9eoQLz5@HT6@bMvCG3wOXj6CJTMfvCd@k4syyJ3TwdB8tXP046QfcvsZU9nDTZwDMQWnZgqLSbwAHcPXijsF2bvfu/e8yn0KcSp3ITjB/zgSi@v/8tliFdmXF83uB7X4zsgEjNOanBzbj7jhnqZ70BQgj9uCEGFk2dcl9M4jee38Lz/PyzrV2UdUOmQzZpxFmLlZLh2y@UrQCZDwX34UziOmwGBM24C/5z6uRwrR1gqpPxPTxyttJd7eGDuietnCTp/kHcHOXcw5nYrj9HY6PnLSyj2fE9Ng2jy8V6aKdaji/jdTw/3yWTS/Xi0x5oPD6ytD12hiOsIQV5enp6yqXrq6YnFlZLZ8b7vsy/wGT4np75j5/Jpr3OKrA0ef3xg3J5pq9XCb2s6mdohGrDjWqvEzRsagM/knbzbgdluYfB47qOPX168Xu@HB/eR266Jx0MkMHg9Lv5hFpJJyOWllnAShhE@jMZKLOo9PY1F4T6W8AY8HE22szy4RqPRgytIZ9ZB6vtxcpIyDGFOgSIwkj24BOPpwXUfejw5SUZpdDSQjBHdCCTDXpfX@xN/fOyUEfJCtMs9c@mGm3x52fzzfHk59tCPF/@8Xox0fk@9Hkj2RuFu9sUzO/YcezAOojDXl5dTDFK4LxC693gfvS8vdhz8erzHNs5TL/AOlw/@Gf91k5gj4t572UMLRCORqNfTnkveSMyT8CWdv5OPUAGPK@wOQ71cbsF9f//5IHwQj9x/ejx4PPAcHwQPHk4ft/S7171HQJaXsnfC7yHfmL3gUdXFh1xulMUj3AfQVSmo6l0STh5tC4P7yXPw@pPgk74D3@f7g2TSLvvg4JeP0G0AHRTmgs8eyC/xkOPT45VQrVF6T@H7hThMhvDLF5AzOw0MGo@z0v/wMONof/SSo/bJ/pc94eWI4icvLvfRlrxS/B73Ed0Kcn1x7QvGPf/oenHtf2m/oOV3wHupgRGNHB0dROxwPAFh/sBrr25GObhbhiFFMgWR9tyjPRQnN/DcC7U6aUtdRQNrb4tJvmg0yobgd/ZDLBeaMUe4ZWLvz7gCLrsDkUSS4tsjpplkYHLRhpafkjgHI6iqCgbRZfmjHQ@zJNKWJDBUJVXFtT6cRIAtrXamMHH9yOyBogGDxZTgM6wI0liSpuPxVFp9Mop5KPSJpw@TYPz8/rd/9Sfw/Xv4/rl9/fP/IxnF39//9n/@3373N38Lkf8Fvv83fP/z73/7b//Y/tL7f4Dv/7MR9w/OdwPO/jKA63/4/W//4u9@/9t/9dfw/V@d71@//v7uL/@T/f//On8Y/Nvf/eU/4I9z8yd/Duj@6s9@92//JVD5lxj@FxCGfyf6TyFIfAH749tIJ7/sc2CJkYdf1pF/Sn5hedD7hF1FAtZ//8sD@snxNuQS5y8sx0O0Dflnv//tv/k7iN2C/JfL7J8JxL2GdCRiWdCfAuTfbNHpQP4pEyeNCvxUC2fn9Y1rPZfKnDMxki6Xsq8uUQcoSoq5fH11G7dTl1mjKxS3uWLx9a1zudXHRBRQwiQiEFsPCzAPxnNIgthvmdMvAfip5eqQWi@TRAKi7fsZ3odD9L7SwPtCiczp7Q1eK5Vr0@XSj08DLwx2hI8kGvf7g8Eg/ODVTz/0Gtz/aQnCv2@i7DFXuFSb5O2dcwVzQMiQkrhXCP1nqtGt2jY@FT8evR8JF4zCoKF0ezBBnOorANM0YeRcjaRvxtUWcw79dYjPgeIZBBbOERSZcEwQe3colExEE8lwKOFPJBORKB@LRv18yM/HE/Ek54fZQYKPJaJJ3p@IJMORSCTpJ3womozDXFLrKDLLgrHIu1yEBhRNxAefjvEJMj3YO2X2OpIME/QPZObpeD/sdZYRZJwgrnDigSMulnXxDG6lHMxOXKEwYCdhjvDExbgWRCR7XCYR5sAubeNNOhFPxcIu1xNNgU@Gc7k6eBPnEvl03OWS8Caa4Lh42uWS8Safz3D5vMtVtm/w43LNlzccBwX18C4X49D/1KXgTSZlw/XxJpTAolyugZ1i3wyXN3EA0/AmHEYExOV6XqFD5IZdVILmsuwbjktnXK6xXYsE/LlcdYovDH8JyJSykyK0gmmaxOGty5WxbyIU3dkSA97k8Cbh3OTtFAQEdCrctVVBHLhcXQh2DVDTLpgxi1SMQOohhL5YmiW4XCLciHNBg3xyz5IWqXmqm4ZPJv3UnXW7szMRU5T6uLv1yeWdlP7rFPzQlEF9PNudMpyPu8ukWdn5GJiitedvPwtMeX43Rd1IKc/LnXIdPzSl210mdMurD03Z@cEUWXfA7LmnDtcnGcwR1xoBTaFXdTZzHYFMM9i7yNzj/UJtbg8xlYUEvd/D@cdgaEY/jROuWNx1eABX1ydXGIIzD@HcYDq43A8ul/c@@fjJFY@6DmGKHXD/yH@CeWzSdeiKx13Ee@QKQdeMulwxEgKhv4PRVuoG3OST68iQrLGhkdDRC1KwOOGOKCXk2YNXwY@/be8XB6x99IJreEDms2fh8/nh6/2EFIPFDJMA7@EcbBTv0QvLHqPi4HF@yDLMKWY6sZf9ABAkdplk65aVciAwLQgGCXxhko3poxObER5X0kPAHpAV@H1wUXPJXovxuN3xkNvtdR8Bko/EtaFRvUeUWGIz1bPkjAt4AZxJgnXvVN@TDIDtSQJJIP0NScbg0LQEAxfnaImHxBVLujAaj8NKLgv77A/w/sODdvT49L9jbFsoxjN7L0wHn5iKJMlR8ggnzmCkH586eS7JPN71nW@QfMTsu5Fod3hr2rJHf/dxxN0LhPWIvre/vw@z@fqpK@wqB5@OWWfWfcrS6fbD6VHkJINrBjAgBx@ejj/6fu0niJmDp5@XawanuDby5hOJMIaEbiQdPFHLnkMlosjXLjH3AM2R7x/zgZKZE0DKHKGZ7dobVcXZTFTnuDZDHuyKHv9mj06ySOXLclt/rNGdh8MrXGf2CIc1@lTr/SPx/qakqF8S4cApXahDESXQ0i@15E/xnxI/XTXKjXL@M3eYOEw8PDjN6efdvJs21dNnGMOUao7ZM3/x6lH@N9rF0d7hyB2OuMOEPJzs2fXm496901A8aArzvUfHHc4TiaOswj21uUM82ZNb25/p1s1kSBdQoKjEH3W6XSX0R1c//7LPsm43Ifz@6f2vZ@UTXUMCEmK/CRzb/8fwQzJlm0JXLOryopeh@dPTT097BAxv4gpFsSP5WGKb1psTAc/sQPvpQIM/6cCkf5JEb7WD41OIMiHCuZcQQvIesCx7HQLbIZmMJWJ7zB9Y9ms7dJC6WrKWJckwx8Nda9YpQ7kScD1fW61bQ@BqvJAMuC5PyFoaGQStDNyUQTNjM86xPDai6MFy23Fzk0W/IIxlGAwp9GRCIqN28uDU0qL@HeQAj/VD90cv84X5ALjGokVdiuDniGE@oG8L3nqWcH7yo2l5cd@f8zIfPjh61rSCpvWEyDGTExngj5gXBtkjdDomwe0Euo1v@0wK6Cmij@znAtQ5sTOZdCCxDSbq7ojlbhB8QGSbCqjNAaElUsqxcnbxH2yw9lhGUvKFYg7ykBMi020pJ7fLaOMBLrR6H2WvUzjhIAqxIDjlFAVHQEAHkR6K2ztEx0zRQyF9hMd0mW5vARTYj35KiZ/ITsZ7vH2E7IheFlXdBMR26R67BuTgySnWqcNy@MJKAAuxdnRooGOc0RX9Tuvhk/L3j17yZen@5cFUckxCa/80Bxc0hn32Is0oDju24NCTcRw2U2z8ox@a9sh2I/Ks4JyYNaNemAPLPzyym2p0xFx6RO8X3P44@s3wxx/Fn0b3w8cj7/DEwqvPN4SRauBRbJAD62R4AuIxulcejyzQEcrjydB76cF7GARhUH9hZJvZptepG9RcOwFacIvU9PoX91rgN9qjP3@v@YDksf/g7mThF044/wy@ygnvV/3PJ7xTDyjTOln4tCPhGL64E7PlogWjtk842orCLAOPerK4Fx5PgB8qZPT58lAZoNO8V32@Ry8UrkLi24xH6o8/Cj71dHakBgJehPop/Cl/b0Hg0XeC94ce4Xj2aXE/hvyHHrieQDGqF4iHfA6vX1a0A31HwGO7Tdek2zTOkLwZkDc8OTm4@3Rwd3Dy8ePifhYYPvpt9h9ya2lA4mdI/NGGC5zn4M5LXrGELvd4XD8ohz8ED0zi8itgPx3c@UcbOW0KD@4gZQRDp0P1C@pLeiTccpcPJcxx27JP0KFncNDpLT25zqSndVoddGCFvClTVBQH3PY8HikwORTwjDk/0XQtIFAITHOOqMTEh9mnT8yyaMenCEpG5dLG@TRMMukJZQauPdHjTu0nLL6lX3ep4aXOXc34aoW7HIHZZTi20V2paqIdzjTEewRBNfCFezmyNZbtSQbKhmoPgKHaA@ECqEWQSY6ecCBPnERorWUDQS7UE7L9GAEe4WKifgL1tu75oEJsMqAz7yBD8fdPqG4CeVIgRJRjWh4EoKswH6ASSAPWQXkkp6DIyI8/Euf2@ATmtHEcCxAM4fo@HoHeUAqFfwelgAOp7IOMoj6khQBtHzAF/R@3Cor80wpy3Jc9kMHX99tezEHqxewZa6btvI9889pkYFt8@ND3nUQcguCfWuqQH9Je/rDnDPeHYKxcVRr1XPUqVYNfmGsk1qdgHq7OS3xzStoITz9rKxr19hOFKi/dXohgwoDdCCKld/A01A65aBRJKFTK@vHBWGD9nr1gBAPq4QqTZNLjhsygbnTZqTJQ2O3zkvHkSupYSE9nDiyPsURy6OCsrh8pWD9RYOICDwzmztN8WwfpDiXTdA5/CyzP06VnBtOHK4b4jAD0QuewOOqzsdx2pk4OuOzqp64zhtJV6CGpPRvBVn56rpdlZ6f9g8FD3jqCJaBEM8kExx0Szo8BfhkILQPhZSCyDESXgdgyEF8GEstA0gnwS8y8jRnmheFwbB2Mr4OJdTC5Cka4dXCNIRJaB8PrYGQdjK6D69Iiq9JiCYqX7C25SbuuZGAaH0ks0/CRIM2ikVFAw7@OjAChoTeQkD3yJhLKS2xHxpOcU1CBLSNQKBRb34P2WcKeeGyq/DYdfrtk@86JhLGKsedJVGBzhgFaKTfDUy1B6LyHBF2kGQbULhFVSQBjQLLASjnJg/xL3kP70SFjfrh2k0YMJ/zqHrLjqW@Qh6cHtNrisyM5tCvZxhbaic1@9oqsGLPhY@4QaVN5uDXS2hgjW3GbWD@igkWOvgMRsiGwDbad0pdl1o3xziLDXy9yC@HOIt8QZeON7sqFvPFQ5CfLrHT8p9hOluXZdopEWxvMAOc0bioDrxoUnyE7@cIfun7/27/@38nvf/sXf0t@9zd/@//95/8Jw/8Jf/5PsFlIaAXw53@BP/8ef/4X/Pkb/PnLjUwUPnzo@t1f/we4/R//I/ndn/yFnfRv/s7lj6wQQQpGrXP@1b/An3@JP/@Xyx9dAf7Vn9mAmMXlf2G2TCsPQP35fyEESkMsK2R//feEuHxgYHgcybu3@/jjxhMnNoIVG@5p6PF1uv0r9gxkO@f1uQCvc8ev73zYAN4N5IaAx0uv@x6YM7anI2ppURB7@FSBE6WbaP@IaMLoZrAL8jbtgNHjrC@4ofb/PTkkbh/CQDR9dO7E1uFO/Z16u9apCOtzsUAdntjooMKwd0UJTG8ZkG86E5ibQZy20Bkpb8uIw98SHl@/HEBcS8lSLA/vZZyylrlh0kOcU4Dhfz3VRaHFYch@9Iyexs04DvL8RoFb6uZVs0Epr2Ngyrh@GGUzK42QhiNoEsi24jcyFm8oF/yv0a1bzuk2uXL@VYfBTxtMzMGmRloVdEJcrm/AIqcdeC9aXOFteJteB@CeOww/bj3asgvYdXNz42I24jiUIaPjoRg2KmWrjFUSv50U2kgKbSQBzTZOqmuiodArGujAgXpx@zEuO9uGitrOthYu7DnLdkAyYC5oLyn6ZXVs9k7eoqYaeVvZvUW@gZJ/PHH6yYNGdc4pcXnfZACc23lOXrflbtTcG5i3DbU7J3J7K2artd7HtJVno1NQ7jGvubRqOT65q@W2C/wKav7R950Fhbh/YkGB7ywoFv12Qa@bFfNuoX@fv99WO0s1sdLwa2R2x9/bGqBwaPxrEL21OkKKDRr0eGHKk3KmPO2pTjw7jnuGeHZ5EsbWGc/GxvkYOIkp6ZZkLw98Hukw5dDRCt54R8SuF7o4r2ToarohmZuPrCm2@7/mxocmRb2rwajmxxM5FOcAc9xyth@P3x5XViObY4Vm7NdOIGqbUWh5Pj0pmmI9PYHxqcreNQPxNiiiT7abwfdVQGgjv2dl2pZHHh1PFrK838ZJ7V07W10RB57yyEl0QyEpAhM6UVJh8kV6gjjAN69QlmAV6QNkaJG2LY8XmdjTh3pX0nR8XhRzv0JfWONGgoTRiNLiJ4KfiBsUOZNoj@gXvE7Wy1@dlVyGPIJ3lT@0jWCLGX5ivOYxctbYUdzTu8XZ2Zbl1X49vbVNemtfp1dWDNN6TTONxNUevP66osOeNQYAXJMR/jYZfucR8TfkbJGyisZj1O0M301iRzJFGP6Q0hSAphzwoAzy4V/dmXC3Irz5Hv@/3oDL7LnvbT5qzNbmoG@GObT96BTNpAdkaKLkAfCCF3XP2@JWop39zrKciQ6d4fmJiyouDV37oWOORpJmrrZ6l4i/IfPoC/NG7qmDzImduIMmY@Ing9D7TZR96kiqMJc6HgfSv4F3WeOqJHSovvq@iqOio0pPt8/O93B@fssUo49gUaDDd0RG8E@83vfFygZRVtJDN@MohYX3@UcX7l6rZlwEPbH3QHQDNOgePXuBnngxmo/m9mObqv3KHkeP2uOP3ZIlfJr1mwwBPtgvZOH962K9X1OfVc@qSt8xIqxgg9tVxiezlhjx2ai3bfjrWPTtmtJVhlWmk2Urb1kn77W48rUW35CKpUzaVsn3ieS3hO67ZW5D1GxkaxWW@XVDyBvMGUFVRdGzidGO@WqL6dobnYBx2GK69s6o8rRDoa5yUk1n4cnIJ7Z94WUUCBbgOoFrE66IEOagT7ZALeuGdu1yyYumDIXRhtXixNyLaItucNG7uY@4AcUsw7iQ@7IqU3y3TPFNmeJWmasesF3kBhAjbhXptAI2z9eaQJVk6x3tjEk4c4fL19Q2fDRdMHDv9YtbcR8qfuKeuA9BIbsl92HOA0rZ3XEfZmnAdB/WaGDgPryEwLpvuX9xHy67BQIYcEsDnzHeUeF4L7oPMx7vC0Nf1LYsN@g@XLUpwHyybylHXuzl1baz66@vVlUlyW8blX6CEmPCRcdq3T/66ZeDfwrqHGgEiR9PSOiAAuMEZGvQ2Bgx7HJg2AjSN0F5dg0fh8ulKWd9Y72GAum@k41FFZSSMdVH7j33tjKyCcNUuvgIVyAQ9ebhbooI/2Zm9i1ynNJBQmkjb5dPuRek9kDHQ9PvAXhzEUdd51@21zYKuwG/j07M/B6db8hZFkcpQmcA7w6ykKk/u79SKWzrV4fj2K2/2UJv1wiwEQNLELuVKNoNnQ42HNqmtLCRPtoWEpqKu33KZh78OJ0SpfdVNqoVnJ75TjKNdmqGimGz83u/Vp2NfEjalgrCxHvu0e5lq3GB6mJMWuu6DUvV7nxAwobO6dDn2iUU26wTpHC2uvHTseK9YWiZ1y6Saq5tNQmZg/ig0Fiw7NLX@zL4@NCvm74uc4IJDjQigo2cq1Js/ar/Cvtdt@33pUG9ZMKrAnYZ1ruH0rfm9VdH2VeUq@ti3zYgJvpJ1rvTOFqVsGY5zA42LPOvydobEx9flWEb@XahK@yvrP0l21Zzgm/w7fXcwsaFVoIx2Y4c4MLsIPQ@o95aJOokuDRagliSg8eu@IrSddW@Tqtd8V1NjCk4RsPlVzewsd3Am42H@GgFjFcst3s5vlqM7lOs@jauqW/sXNi7Djp6ia2OetqIBHVP/ddWLloQUX6qZsul4i0MuvF43Pt2KwJ7LeRdj@PMV7cJVtOWkB/P9aAvPEXfiZ5uWB8fNNdblzIaAcaAQPdtbPFz@rjX0WUb@vxV34V8NuwGRx1cg3U3ELa0Epo6Ag7ZisNX@7BWz4HgIFmat8BvP52t4a4RSgdu6Dw90eHr6Qmdc56enFEMm2a1jfSHPed1QKGNt5bubXszvfPGaFwAGA/td2Y6C3DOY/G2H8oevp929b7pVa6xZilLZwdcH8ItqpVnhCfMe@3X2i5j7LfPgqR6QhGcwoai@NylnQuhceGTulY65Xy0DR0889Ec6ZrzetqB/QpjegKluVx6pWSPtalA3UDsUujjohsU2Q5Zy30x@sZJejyu/XpPQbOXkJe88ROpG6Q7PqEkTDkGysg@9mnl@mF6aSZKMPXRAh63VWmIb30E2d2xmnylQKv08kq3C4LEOicQ2w4udXwRZECXA5n1O7yb9N2dznF5jk8YParSWQcGdnq2zqMwSSgG1lTSD5xdf4Gx6CZD8MwJjjppUSj4xuESt4MJ/0bej565d/vKLz9exPfR84Qtaz@Zphh42vBE0Db47DywtrE07WxaUj2wsXO5PFqFcY7COaH7lEH0URt5XHuu5YEzGLTdJgRVXJ7U4MEzQg6ZDxpVPOgBRkTbtwYMXA2NNrq95l25pGrkBxIO0RenQXnUSqXFAg57Z28LO6RBViTW9u5zFIzrh47rB9xMZD7soS60ZQ3zL0UZw/TgvLUsk48OOntDBbuy3QWWN9GNmzBMNT7sKPijx@UDLD6X17WFCeCd3Y8PtuZ9mxWUovcPbL0Ta@X1VCpVH/JG9SzVTfVS1Vu4T3NFX6sfybFs7lztpLKF9vxMj9cncoir316n22FfJd6ZjZTzYeZ8lGOUyO3QdxeeJc8ji2gmnEmJ3I18VpQj8cyNfGNKKVVKspP@4LojVUdt3jCVy9JVqbpg843rZve6L9@1Wv24VmNG1bt093omXSda2qTZSBbMa6mZKVmDUt8a8/NyvBVrTDUz3aynexfzwnQwK8T0WyWauZbiTXl0PhXn0ZF43mDuJvVerHY@HyT5YWeeypid27jPx95m0t3Eudi5ky9qmctO14i2o4NaUghPhhfyaN67PNeei/1MbSL6Rv18ITZhtEphMpUirUFbPdfuqs1mO5uuTAe8eTfq9COtq7HVThixcHicknr9SLQwtoxEMZ26jFvZVKGZV2@a1t28magw1rlVjzcuxKTqm5QtMTzONliTa84ulMvaNHYequvn2oVa6FcGZ@OzijoaD7IRpVwfRozuTb6th0Ln17XJ@W2RMSIXrdtEtR9KZMWZyF5GdX0YridLReNqNk4/l6VWRqylpXaMS0dvcnz/qjwXy5NitdqqjFqNYdy85NW7PNdnyjdiLZUe5IvDBF8vzQuJs0JtnMkUZpN2SO7qqXGnFb66iU2LJanQumbD58LYuvIpmbLK9i8uzHmzcVm4KZl30K2vLpSIPJ@lm2lDfs5mzKtqkS0Zg14t0tc6o2ZcyejiRaUQsQqD1Pm0dZcspAeSXGkP9EG9pbbGlpLts3lmnhlcN9rSNK8spkIuUmxes/1cVbTiqW64xvZluT1Qy@aie1ZcdGvjdreTLJ9xWen5spNuRqu5EX@VNyMlbc7c1tOysqhey/ygkjwv3LVzKeVKi2Yq0qhydj6ZhUK3ilyZRhf87KafjygzMcIVy@mbK9/1RajqK/rS6YoeLneZUDZ/1upGL316XlqwRVl4jmd8xngcmWXH@J7PYkNTjWFU5RL5uq8XN41W8upq2jYLN9VMS1QXiburwSB2V2VuJgVTN0KJi3wqyVYGnHEm9EuFu7ii5SPT9JmaSxZai0bCyhXHauK82M1eVI1sfSjeJHPd2nw@6CYupEpxkGKkRLZa7be7zfbstmZW5txVROy3fbmzXOm5C/24WcuHLhrpWHdcDTcvs9qkUs/7FvpNqzjKlAZ8rpIYx@rx8JCZzC4SqZqlKaPs2VUydj1WirlUttvI8Lok3TyLl/xAqNXnXMKMG9f5m@uR6bPqbT3S7qXD8@urW7Z5Z5rRc4W5m7VihdTAEC87M@vCjNe1kF6@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@Pt8qIj9KNNS67GyjOLeQaTpzkpNvLtWVY25X518qydzcY3TTbSOBsWG52Jr5@8u52ElZsyVyylm7IwLlx341ajNBtdXaiyyg5D5S7LTBuVxcKSUnquNL26ncnNxSKlpM1nfnbJCsWzQvbG8iVz@VS2XK8JhlounxWzKWE4vZoWb@I@aVG76kSVwfMdU9E0NWTc1dR4mguboUY0u8iI/TNufJYe1i/qSX7EN86bV1eXfE8Vh2L8tpyNta7EVip1cTm/kIVmpTKqXDbqTNmn3dzd1dlyXS0m5WKhWtejhYlx1WrFhameuha4QmTYnhZn6enVeNwaJi98t5YkhPWFJPHVqVpkpXOQnQQjjSeVTKlizkPPi/5zd5LVb5rJ1OgslsrM5c5Emiy4VHbiY838bNqJKaNEqH47O5Nvxatu97Ka7oVHk1E9lokyF0n5Smu2M72r5Fy6PC8282NLqnXaEcVncqN@/TrVMBviXDkTY71Jw7xVofPJo2g9nUma6l02cWkoPi4hphmxdSVU2GIvelO66OjTzOyqOc/ClCPByxUuqs@15jgx0M4vzfRl6/kykeg22ucDKHjcu@uJSsOX7rSla1ktMXc3l81BrjJusv3rm6t4pXHuSyzCxtmzqPfOhOS8vihznCQnu5PCeBYeFcXEWeKyLKoXs1K1IUvdWC10rZ5pCyarxXtcSuank6nG@ubRdCLXldONkmZkG@J5XNIrAsvOWndWuXWTuAydcddcbTjlQubVlOXkW02Z35Zub0MdJj0xL0etGj/J@c6t1G2tXxXPVLbUqhYW@ryYC5mNVCkjX46n81FxrhjhO7F4llErosKDWRKNdetGY7BIT9pMS54VM@lE/C50DhJkmmpyehsRJNEcdWd9tng1Pldn/fGgafiGM7bqu7udRZO9Zs9kxWKxXipMc0ZUvzD7GhOLiaHzljGKm9Xn4byQsbK9ZkONZJLNbrt8fste1eXL5HWmdheXohW28CwlW7UYJxajLZHlq/pwYsGIJHYHTHHOdQxRlQwhPi4/R3Pjsa8zn4wt3@gufnaZaHUHGX4iCr5wqq0/C7PmhcoppbjUNcut6eQm3wILUWtOGhqTv2uMwpfKuVw7b5avBnwlVV1YbDrZEm8i3VuDlzV5Ug1b0YuC1I2LcjZ3N@hnzwvPBe5WfuamvGpcX4fz5zwTl31pS@@obPN6dK0tQoKUui0nrqadRWbYK8nSeSGUNW6rsU7tUlBzMIwqz0Vu1MyfFe86bbXHyrpWrlU5jrmLhXKtm@ozP@lcVxZ1fXZudC9SFTV8Ixc0vXLT5LPXBluKp/PXmX71LjNPxCqG2pbq3URdG/rOwroopLRijIlLEyndbLENSQnz8dmiLQwklr9rDQaJc3YRMxdsSjOn/UR3kWyfDfnWXUk/q88H7NlwdldJ3/BjycfzFXHEXFuLSvTsrOW7nJ81Cl21UZBFVhjO@@Z5eixdTNvXsZQvMeLqvlyn2ZsVK91RK8fG2@0EXwuHWxHruVOZm9clppktnofj2bk1k3ODcWmWOB@lYrX5rHEdiQzu@rNyoharRmf8RB/k0qN8N8rqN2Zcm9XPu/m0lJOvZPNq0RaHTGwxLhXyiZwvKgm3lds7Ts6xz7WOavW6cv3yJlyLsWL0vFyZ3t1lU@wwLvdzBfUMxsSpcDWb1/q3g/Z12QwrjF6@9RVii9iidndd6miV1sVVrz3txuMV47zZT44Xt6OqUvWNFo1CWz/LVoZqdnEDAherJqP9hpprtJSbbJUrM1aslZqCDc6ni8q8yxai3KWscRez4VnyZtiKDW4Hzcykejsb9GO1eFQfS4u41XqOjqVG/PZiWGPF9u205wudMXptMb/JXUeMYmk6KloVXbrkEqHi3aAxzI0bvmHmMt@2Mi1u1A61itOxLxMFqyBx1UyGSu3LfrowOLs2z69DSaaeV@bjRP8sduarwGAy7pvlRFMNqRO2xarN6UQaDDmhlBWaxqzdyBc7pU4owY58SnxqXcaeL24rd4I1imgsY85jnangO8@BBZFVbqM1X9MacUOYi3A3k/Cl1g2HTO2mVhOtjB4fNMJJKZI3mprenOn9Zki5PosPpqJy2WfS0qITURvVVqc0W0w7yUGkI9QmjVT@RmuFM9qoNzMNPpa8DDWF58rQCJetUaXYENPa9VAQ5KlvpqazV0ZtwnS6pVSnlX8ey5NmpJyKpOY3HS4yvpv0eW1xk7sN9SvtVE@eVluRRXUaTnfOeK06VEZDI8Ry9aaWGyRmjXPpkrlY5KR5L3GdrjQjjct@chBWu4NahZsPyoos3t2ZY75w2y1e851CtJm@Tg7OZTMlxRtJ@aLPzkrt8l0s05EiHOPrFYZsKFMUwxe5G591IarRZ2XBl6xFUtbmpYbSrnUnqVGx02@MS@lzNs2HJmez8jB8XmXDYyE9TGQvjVtDZaRcNDVrlK9iZu8uZTUjeiU0SYzuKkr3JtSp9ARxyMUSoIOvOu27eSNVTU@Lt6XzmpnSugvJZ0wvtbNCPp/WmHO5VXo2nwVdHqcijXLx9vr5OmV069G2ZRb42bPEzuda@SIjivPbVMEclJoXNa0Q54ad9FX8utcpag29ooQvGTEZH9zEWa0mXow5KVJJRfLPzTPxuTCJVfWBZon13B1vlaqg7ArRRnl0Ox0uMj1OnoUjuRuz3O2M7qC39hdMaHxeve1U5b42m1YvrOZleFjjB82pOohpwsgXySXLZYHvhnESFr3RtaGuXnatm1ppcmmwbG8RG0ujM@lSYYqhUTdVqMYuQsLZ2W022eCHz0UplLiKjFPTULl65dOi0ihb6A5VLjOo9qVrBaYMrVilf8HVSkqjezfO3CTnNWZx25aT2kVrql9mBtPsYNKvN2ZhmF7Vm0XTrFVvrE5hEmpfxNV2udepZ/OZazEjCGa8rGVy5cFo3GwPp@eRKNPPh2/6V/ELpRsbxAvS/PZyPEpWLhaFTO884rvVLhLWrWCpz2W1/1xqW1b7Oa40a9cXbCsdFzXueR63bnot1mTOE8PcWUSKLwo9Pt7QhpPxuFOuanphXrm@AjbHQ@H6WZtNjVrXFavZOZfEm/MGWPoXulSo3VyMamc3551xR2PUMIhvhjUuz4pm/iY7uOOnheq8rfC@QflyWo7Go3Ky7ZtEh6XeOBuNtuLDi9Iknx0ZsdkVaP1uZV4pStXSFcMPr25zA9@FzPMJ42rRnESqKekm1r6aytNINJuaab1EosHNri/OxOtEe1SYDhsXfPeand4lB@ZQaAjVlKjLZSb9PArPszMrx0Vzl7Hzm2upH5t2cuNQITWttQoxK1mSW63I87Q6HUilPC/XZ5NpqJIvX1taJDprXt8NLqEVoozYnV3n4tJVROpwyuIuY@T1ttYQUhx7wYamjea1T@9qzyXJN6iE8uFRLMfNKgLMjO/S44tOrN3oq62z9Hmyx3QiYs5XN2OFu9jzzfOVYtz0ffEhqJyEXJ1cX4FJ0rYa9cjsWk7e8otmJtES2vkFn7tkU5Hz83GyEApdFJPFW8asRYcgLc/T0M1FVg1dV5r1yNiXLWVnnV7trlHNTK8Sd7f8sNKqTS5wMhZmualc7lcb81J@1lCkWG5Qzclpxle4nprl5EiuZps5g6105HykPzg/y59J40txPMtpPq5baMwnz@OhlLi4UgXJ0PJVq5cSw7eJQXgmFkap58smMz8Xchd8JtFMGANFvOiXGmbfnLRGspKKPEdnPqvaryiX0Wy1fqP1G71SyRAzV6G4KWUHtWHsrtGftSdSrnPByFZyIqqzs1LM0tLzvHLTuLq@6NS4uVhJXJTyxoxrs/nnGjex2EaiVql32yVDKfZh4PTdNnQ9oYJKsXr6NSOMegVu2kxddhJdM3PGJYoXs3JDKfm461y1nw2ZE8PH9oblUHah5y7C8jTerV5fDjkjM@n0fJeVOHvXT@vTEhO1OuGWYA6SVZm/vW2yo1x1YZpXiUbbd3mtslI1dBdPny/4ejs86ox7t4nb4dnk@fb26rndrJ1Dc974pFjt6pnpXl@em3E5KfKdRjpTTOmTEXdhDKtyZFjUbxuhW9l3O8sWps@hSy7fL7T5Uqm3WKTFC6OlJbLD9lVGmPcbiSYTzpW5zl1YGl00ss@3@d64L2aKMzF8o5@bvptIaTY@MxLxGB9JTgQz3BwOm75ESlV88XBv3gulc5NYlu0Y1RaTK/syLV2HXlC9iwkl1ox0SqplNuL1Wi5ZzeQz58XL3I1cTNYKws2N7/a6kMml6rGLy94gcnnLm2k2fdXr10JMv5gZdFjLSoyVmpI3c2dGdta7G1wPx@1pfFI0bxfapTBWukNeFkaDVlGLx1LXzedomQvnrtjc3ULVQvHoLMl0RLlzwarVwU0roeTO2Vu1BxPoLMj/4OZqbIiyYfaSLaj51UKLZxrlbtM4V3sVoFBtj0eiPEwqg54UvmOqbC2Rj7fUS1ks31aH8du2clO/CMfl8Qzmr7fZxaWcZaHVG7e13pi7ieXAdI1Engut3vB6Umqa1Wi2WS9WIkzzuZqV@UKuWGzeWR2@VOa6@YnViCfOc7w4TA9KuXm6nS5M82Kjde7r@0L1jjjJN1NqrtkRzNn8jktyRkruM7F@7CotZ3lrGm3KRiRz0SuHBbWgz8oXidGwWrkIpS9y17I@MLj0dWr5iTXnyaESnXflVOqsWbjNdJnUdSbbDzVlU6xqvmmBgqXzqvCHX31UiGQYGgVjJrrSIfS9xs4xF0dfOXiCnjyBj7dvnTuBzj6bBwnIzvPVQAuU43c18AnhQ7sQurcZxJPZcWvx6PXeYoBfHidAL3iOBzmgp7HLWxuhLgMzr8j4qGhfI4DueNIdFNwHo48n/2Aewhdo8C9RApvoE3UeyhvvN2mjHMFzPvA0Q@7xaGPL08NvUoMEQpMJmgz89Lt@wFMVfoSMdAs4V857d23rc0db@YE4c6TRk0ZcgaCLZnVOxUBM2yjs1sT41dkMDD2QZbmx9pV3zQgsn@BiSXq@B9H8ln94n3z0H4gnLiJZiqANzbEx7Qy6em8iE5WM@u2ZOF88ExKNkDCUFfqR@LBMPnbC0pNA4/CbIEnOORmKfj7Rg43xfCx6ziCeaO0mJLA6Xeoj8dKAH38OXUdvpJQcDJdSaB/yMbyPPZ5oJ9zR8F57PNJ8Pq/lO7F8vM@DET/y3qPR2PFEvLce6VP77AG5Wj5ajyexo@@vLpOKrok93W0S@lLRzWdO6Dlgyw40FEab/WkiiZZubMbIKE/CcKsjvo3CXWLhVU5FX8JZ85GEW3erUwlUfB0z/nwYxyJHb9Oxhh8@4BEaR47vxGYFvjCjcVtVxEPmA@UnboHj4/SHh86hMCJBuf3wgcYpdqRNC1FMDyYfLVNFfTR3Mis2yNOyLscbKE89uLfq9X8P5BKqDTL5hO/NMQDMBrHZuwVOADXdGvXaVGG4KGmrfVA8x8d7hKeckI/LtOWJPwiPckPP3XmyiEJP6YHLMXFA6RkYxOucOEFj7xV86I26Epy67aQP/fFwRPefgza9DkfwVX9PI0ExVjmD5hjffuohPDJDWRKNLYCBFzyKbSJY0mbTLNsCHd/ow1dYH8RXoW92AIJFwTDmqBvx4QPE19Fpng/2uyQ9xNJtx0qbDCcvrYbXaWpgHJ7T6x65Dwn1gzuCKLolerSR2odUrOs7yUNIHgpW753kHuIem@8lG5CMb5h8J1mBZPuZyN3pOqTbO/3vAFjo5Qni@mTpT5agqB77QA88CuTFVtge4vMtGbsSAWI3jN0e2/mJczQK@Wi3ji1sW@IF/ZOKlQ2AIu1xOg/er6WFpuIxxh5bLjbKtHlCvpBvFuY4RwKLn2hJoHaxfO/BFn6yQQD0P1Cl5G36snC7tVcV3ZKfIAw7XWxtYFaY/PLL1yhzBHFb/vjHpfTZLYR@uBs1tLm1xmO/AG/drnamhZNpdx7n6JhN7bb0kVjXY9kpQ2sVYvetdb@WFa0DZQDij5vR6PLkJZ/WMffmIzlcaY81H@1u8W0@ht5ID3pE0R7pJ@11UPx@rgoo95BTgBG5vVYWeE6YcPSGneYKOrANfQrQK26@kjNxS2acXvprK/t9tdkD@minprw5shWtCKbhqUPgDvIEu103dYKNbN99aMfji/2UbWTKO8js8/SeAIF1DDTgyLZU48sxUdGC9jOpoOe5UMRPXcxtkJc1m5bK6nv49M/QuZBxzpA9xncdbasksoM1b8BX9UZ@nb7ucq@qZ2v63ZW7tx9qdn9yI43krTxRqfsEo@Qh4cjq4KYj8vJtPfSP48yXdfNt2Tum531dsWz0pSR@jwi@vMPobwrZdhVCj2SL40gC1QzfGJLoIYS7B6W1a/3TMmbpdmn37XctMKTqaDsdabYRLhPAUN7M5XdsrtO16nROX3yylsaNf22F4SsGbakAk/2I2VTnOJ3L08F7M3Z1dBTlyGYKPsmOFqaxpEyRl7YtmMHLfEHxCZvZZjLyE/p0V9c7nqXB5BgMFMPyhA4A8tvHWa3MKtu8XBcPxTlGL@k6p3wsx90jiPnoRNFxBSLQ@HRkE4k46NJuc4TdZsO@UUz6BkyajqMRFLV8@gCdFW3tQw5fxyP0ygT6sDPTUuPjmWT05EpHz9OReEs9uDKCho6h2Bz21PrYhfGrhkCYU5hor8@3pG3wsmOVwT7D0znd8svm1EU5UoJoE68afekF6T1aUXN87MJiVgL/8oe9j@zYNNi2orGSNgGjuj1n9oik2S9@OsS3gwcS6CiML/d2tAn1y6ZOiCAm0FJYWlCTph7nBeB4iqjLy9hn0lGnRZ7BI4Cp37gqTTpg9dsntox0c0Z/5zBZ4ILjkaXTFKcgenYd@UX5ZX2eKkefInJmDA45xxTPGsaDzxfYsXPbVzLA2wYSj@cbezdQ3GNOqnBdDy4Xth8S6viT3j8yZlASxB4SgbL3iz2dguaikvzCmMumx7PWkBX48AoEVfuUiRH1HcUiqHVizuk9VB/veQzYMdTFFeXemacw1CEYU1RdH6GQoyso5j8GBtiM/1CrZ3PVatB5bYftsY5e7rYfMz4iSA@so68gWLnxorc6HhdoN8oHrCzitss7WSOn@pfyCIt12IRdYYrstHmF5xHaNQjw9O5NNVbwXhucsoQ@7uTcmchLzjnV4/8v7uiaE8eRz@NfoTCVHJ4YA9nM7dZkko1jTHAV2KxtklCzuRQBJ3ENHykMA9Rufvtdd0uyZcJk5uoe7gVsfXS3Wt1SS7K6n8GOQt7l1cpKtYqsJgsrrHj3Q24MhkN0BNGJJzOg2I7HYyCa8@Jdzg58RI5I/IcZ/vQL4rzNiOf5lVf5lUK@yfM5UXkpc/g0zwt9UguV3v@Vl3thpbyY8QrXKYNGux55lzJnc4Xuk7fKpiYs0pK88FnWlVwqs4zPhYyKkvOvHb3Pc/YKdTIBz/K/8Hwh30ei5zMqC2XPi/jxXxMdFJMPBnFlcUtKzWky/p1vP2Y5NMIydKvEq2N/k9hxpRQbImI4qcAwAUJMant2mkM5rMsRh3SmdPb5vGSKLanfy9tk8HhTrxRrh44oXCKch8S4Nc0kgIey9xQQBBMFjUnNPZOVN6LyRgGLpfYkWk16Ci0qODRtW8VP8bPuv/FHKnuROFnu/e7Md5zyNW88v2lRZBANunul3WwqjiaL@TLmiaJRb8wiOe7NNsTdg4Q3wxXo8AlHigxnzO@DPMyW09FeNk6oA4UcKV7xPcsRnM4L1KX4fq8LMfNF@3f1g3Y5mIBVOI7XzEKbekDe8LXCZZtFnC5S0IEYGjhn6fL5eZwIv25sRdc5eDvrRx/xMkIOUTEaTM3FC6K8vIFP4nIMVDKZj5BXeM8wz0iXj4881DrDWK4wtD4kAHJhatZ0w6PAoxu0I37lJWZL9OOKA/AYln0KEbznuPbQzgNaaaYmLxbxpj5w/Z4uwASChs/I5yG6Wv2kaX8sk@FX@5Id1Wq/1mu/1BWWya3qmvnLMQWTlyaSzDiq1Wu1j/VjTbNnzxt@tbE81BHWcQUBGqyNE/0VyGb8DWOtahbMGFQwBdM/jeff4pGpaUE8oj3g@yVxBEV5mcbcizL5ecUUsK3Q3z2Yu5PUYLDsesLhBf9xfua@a4fkWMPQ8A7RczyfJAt@02j2LRkhA@W9qYfZeDxb0UY0Xlni/MBKk3gBTPmgsyJJ5JdW0EK2C7mLBW4MREj4wf3sG/mRFmwAOzVB9/t0AUhDJ4oIQUXG40krlAC@4XiQTFCcdhCAXpZyDkgCoGmj5TB@kwaNiPgvaZCx7kez4RI98w5kz1Rh9JuRroC6x/MERt@cwdQrVE2hHTo4arkhC/1mdG0FDoPnbuBfuQ2nwS76LGo5zPa7fQprxVp@G0aXkFleA1K9KHAvepEPCSUrhJolytAsr8@cm27ghCHzA@Z2um0XoAH4wPIi1wkN5np2uweT9aXBAALz/Ii13Y4bQbHINwirrKbl9ZjfZB0nsFvwal24bTfqE8amG3mIrAnYLNa1gsi1e20rYN1e0PVDh2HDtIYb2m3L7TgNE6NjeT5zrhwvYmHLare3Gupfe06AxBdaeeEAldZF2yFM1M6GGzh2hA3Kn2xgHhDYNljYdWwXH5wbB5pjBX1DAA2dP3pQCDJZw@pYl9A4rfwDrkC/2L3A6SDRwImwdxFGbtSLHHbp@w3idegEV67thCdMa/shMawXOgbDWIOEGmAAtyAfni96oUt8c70I5oxeN3J9T4dOvgbGAJUWVG0Qg32PtxaY5Ad9hIp8oA4w2HXLgfQAeUrcspALIXDNjtRigBCYGKnNZJ5z2XYvHc92MNtHMNdu6OjQYW6IBQAm4r22AGmPWo39BHTxRxBWTUquQd3J3CazGlcuUi5KgwSErpAWYpvdEjwHXa5qO4/c3jzAe33KJ7ZC3nYSb/sNByw@Hp2llKf3YNL5rXh4V8iDiSbLhFdxCkpz1d0ovl8@3iXThxkuzbNq/AR7kj4aGJ1Ix0iPf2pvxJoVB@VU4f37u7sr6w7WueHdnW78TM0CGT@qIbywvlVKF20czwYjWuYX9pZURp0dCF/vBne8rO61HGSbDzqrVkexqIaXFxGw3CYSQQkA2AhHRrrVOJgyBSUdMRf3iihixvZmkTzenKXwM/07f@Fzg5IAgzP/bqFaxTUskYGRT1hGPyChoCAiMgh9B5A8EEozjeOvj@Waig6X/GKDSpd1qOwCloGPZf0H1e/jx63qle36RCzeNSVjRbqDl27aUTBn9CZYxkS/mHNqWZlv7dGfLqkhRGAU6hwVXWQVX5@UD3h19C/K9wr1k8yVOIUD6Vg37jUu5mpHxydb6a0snesW3jrH2DYw332herf017rlBUDBElx@AUuSDT9SrVaVOmCVkT2ZFUZf9U9YaJWMYE7FqfoppmkdPeRzd8FqfZiM58lapR6G4cvA6lz0mk0YOZHa498@/vrPE0143J8vbgz@30c8GAKSuAtW9CoBM42yFC2xwe5pvgqWo0T3wd7DghhVUXYaJQ7ApM08Z3IbgcfX4NtA2NwUIwxMMchGCYMEzEsM7@fHe5qU152aKQSgXGiqjq2ZDNZk4Q/AVCIZGHIvmeMN9doafxB2pv5SxbMGCQESIhZPnhcbkFxYXNC4V2pKhwO0tqFrxVjELEk5fh7Ib5A4Y3DMJC8MeAef3oRsK70Idi12NOordTvVBCL2tqmQQVoo5BKg6M5SqcE8MYGUGyFv8NgXwYEwC0M9WIsQ2NjMalZk8B6@5ywUQ0C@PTuFLjo4yDB9ZriRqgui@P5/MXSMqg1ECv@ggW0Bll8eZXzOcmgT@vwfOvuLSyp69UY4J0JixTtI7q7mCCgn0iW6eJcRZBiHlQeUoaRVhkOTRfqySMbOApv@J34Q/P8jT3bA/wwLToCec4vG4WS6jH@SkwSV8wpWr8SUZCW/GFM@U8u5qSb1czAvasc8ZQ0Tn@Gt@cESsED0zkYm9HlIsfIOBqCQ476Gqr/owJeU@GkAK6dz0t13/KR/Ph1OnssyIJecKl7BvTXI5jLkJ3L4ovMj/BpT0LUxvso5@XmkMQMXXDCK3W/YflriMA7rNOZgo6sfaNMj03ISTWRDXWp4Lk41oVpS@dfiC6N8lhnJ3BcwRb8f7Cs7DsGYQoUBX56AyAGEvn1SGyzYBjjPkNCd7UZPL7TLz8QsjsEiYQikeZlF5J4jHTzQmhmnIuFLA512IEqEsz8SMZvu48UKp4sxh04@RHJorLxPbkwQidiLzMwIOfjqJnCdJtlVRj1tU6K8ZtT3pl@nGFA45ltcsoRZiAClumA1WWdAwaDGP9fuUo78ENl6VsTvTsmvypCfV@LWHK3cAQuu9PfTnCNgca7QuoR5KOfSYPgVE0tSRpNVJVnDH@GqiJbLmEawZqCIdbuM/pfvLghQVra@gWWlP6fZJtInPpGd7kvzBZ@47mZPfXwS@8yn0CggDlLwg1lhBiHJaDfhR5qvtY3o@w8)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- PATH (133) [local](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pathlang/files/PATH/0.33/)

### Explanation

PATH is a 2D language with explicit entry point `$`. If there are several `$`s the last one is used.

PATH code is on `#s8␛dgg` line:

```
$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._ #]
```

`>[]` are for bf/smbf, `_`s for dobela, space for incident. `#` ends the program.

Fixed YABALL return value as [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot?page=5&tab=oldest#comment348471_142157) by Potato44.

#### Haskell

Some refactorings to remove blank lines. `<` from `1<2` moved to `//<*/`. TRANSCRIPT can be reduced to

```
>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPQs""o<>-}
```

runhaskell can accept options for particular build phases. [`-optL`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) passes the option to literate pre-processor (unlit). 
Unlit can be configured to ignore all errors (quiet mode, `-q`). So if we run it like this:

```
runhaskell -cpp -optL -q polyglot.lhs
```

then it will not error out on code lines adjacent to non-empty text lines. (I think `-cpp` is equivalent to `-XCPP`.) Ignoring all errors might sound like a bad idea in general, but for polyglot
it is better to have as permissive parser as possible. Just in case, there is a full list of errors that are ignored as a result of `-q` option,
obtained by examining unlit [source code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/utils/unlit/unlit.c):

- Program line next to comment - this is the error we want to suppress
- No definitions in file (perhaps you forgot the '>'s?) - no lines starting with `>`
- missing \end{code} - for Latex style literate programming
- spurious \end{code} - same

So the only blank line left now is before `>main=putStr"128"`, it is for Retina.

Comment: YABALL is using its current cell value as exit code so it is exiting with 50. Can be fixed by putting a `>` just before the `@` and a `<` just beforre the `!`

Answer (score 6):

## 137. [Bloated SNUSP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SNUSP#Bloated_SNUSP), <s>6129</s> 6109 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVk RcRcRcBkBkBk
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOxx4O6O@MoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++. _++++._#/+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWWW/WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                    (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉
1  1  ! !           x
2   !    !          xx
1      !!           x x
1  x*               x x
53  +               x  xx
1  x*                x   xx
51  +          xxxxxxxx    xx
1  x*          x             x
34  +          x             x
15  +          x         ?   ?@             !
1   *          x        ?@    ?
1   !          x          +   *
1              x        ?  !  ?
1xxxxx!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?x@x?
  x            x
             xxxxx
            x  x  x
            x  x  x
           x    xx
x          x
x         x
x         x
x        x
         x  x  xxxxx
        x   x x   x
        x   xx  xx
       x    x  x
       x       x
      x       x
      x   x   x
     x   xx  x
     x  x x  x
    x   x  xx
    x    x
  xx     x
 x      x
xxxxxxxx

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002375 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6241 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1bb@vMlhj4vIn5B3mpLft8kqwLSd1lW95bV1u2LMm6Wr58/iiKlChRJE1SEqX9@aDnJUl3gplMp9PodJI@3ZkMpoHJQ5DBAAkSYIDJa37FeW0M5vyDM6uKpC62vPf@ulu2xGLVqlWrVq1atapqsdjnjNHvf3@AP6iuysuhrJrIFAwTDXRpLuhhlFuiz5xkxCNRisJQWX04mwqKaRxTB4hFSFJ4aQD3yFQngiKtBB3iIwhpujrUuSkyR5yJBIPnNMFA6szUZiZSxf3ZoggVp@pYCuGcU0kZApgp6JoumCQ9hlBbkblpf8C9Som/KlDTId1ABUH@efqziXh1OuWUgQGQCYQKtVyxkn2FIYnQtaobAsbDC4ah4sgUQlZR4F@BpgGU0yW1kq2ev0piGXQOpHOaLFiI6xumzvGmpCo4iUU5WeVMYYCa1XazvpOTsLauq4MZj6ttjgRIxqwSJVkwKB6qdIY0p4HCOIAOkC5wAxuMElUd4SxoOpGRhHhNQ32ZG4V5JEsAW2JSSMCcRStIl0cGsrQpYDDUqbBNh4EUAegzNIGXRIknpSPBMgXFgEoYYSTxE7SQZBkNBBkybEjig4AMzYytKJuAMDVQKQQfXntVgfXdoQAwiuAyQdCAuZgJKm4L4IjLi4XOaRoQCcxsAuGmNAWRkkyvgQTOkLDQQhZDUAaEf9panFXEKdu1RHOJQxzQO9MJbkPQcRuFCV40EnQBUHJrgfItdMkEFmD2ZlFd4HTU0gXBvyvaO0VCYSouwcQVCZPmOz31FmslLzSjnSPMaSZ1oEdbN5cUh8IZdPh0At@Mx3NCFasF9OXwAYdtSYam1nQf50eZXyODfngQ4GuxfXqov1CAlQKuyIhWNZPmQhoQGDKBQJrDQRwKzSNhTd4qGJ2@aost4bKhBtAaqKygTpDUjJ/pOu6tG6ZyE6i0rCpD4CdUVp8pmB8KSjDQBLwKnS2IhDlwTVXsNlIXhMOtkQSNZuAm2eofts4hDAWtA7LncNQt11DlGYGDnIaJBRC4AlkxxrKIOkjkJBlngXSMyqZaF4yZbOI8M2WAWx50ijAII5cMXh1goKk6h@I4QEoioC9Nt3ogIQqAoSFUUlWc9Nt/9q8GwyHgyfK8qg8cce2ggcoT7cgRYkHlICywqsLJhCyAC@LS7exQwJyTpQHoBMyPpVMEIYKUulBn8gCpUKC@kKBrjbg5dEdRFHisRTAdtkINoik3sfWGZEsuVHzK9aFhSQGkbFLtEPqch1biBeqAyExoOjPFFAppReQ16B99n459nz4@CECcP@w/OqTp4QkIXPiIRMGd92uS08nuKDzD5AxVGlDa0hypSgSFeOThM6omKD7vDg5v0Kv3vf4w1mc@/4mU4cOipAx8XpDxHJTr9Z/wGf5eOn48eZV7u0TAssBYcG8VfLzfQ4HGIX1iTk85SQlrS9QJOaGtNNV4whzHyeGtaMyX13FzO@KAjCdYLFUsH6CGwoYsCJqPCbN@rCUw3N5q44R9FX2Fw6nwsfQY8B54A9tVJxigpjsVxX21JalYa8naaAY6GpiiGBpobx2LLs@B8BhYiZswqAdRn4g10fygWIhKXAheXUB90KOuGJEeafc4nD@E9aSDYdODXLjdDi0Mtvoz6ALo0qbxRinL6gIKJrTh4Qs0iIIL54bQRJDZrlDWrpBdIonZrdpEAb2CsfUFlAr1JegLuNeBandEf6uOAB6N2DCAze4rWypoyi0BC28PiZt@gyQRutQUtIS@RLyAVQ/oIMEeV3AhM9INDTBnsGHDhCLx@G5Xe9PTTJ3Ohu5AV6/or3YoXPntPoX1DRKFBZI5ZTjjhtiiUiALx/OCZjr6CmpimKCRXg87JDLkjKFhY0Qdfn5dNhlLnNF1qwys6@3Wc0ZEDisZx6YKyaBTEedYhWgg6aCd5OXr0gFg/qpwz08YZIeAnzzvkOAaAiBkgiXwMxOUGwjyYiTxI5BdTJ1iq0d7LHpdPERtlw4KPiSui8bEsGc/RKgwvY7CZLyLIoRb9C0eGGMxqrOdCNL42xFfx8wZ0z2I1TWJMB5sxYZpLgyy9w2cU1VR9yAFRq7RYpDdFLsdwCBrYmMQxi/X@iKddW0hrpsI2gy0B/R8kL@RaWrGMQwXkjma9cMgKXRLX5bNmoKFhTb1pWSqdrgvq31Qzwb0T9otgeZnfcl6VSESt27DsUHNwQ4TDZSBAfx5BlLn84oGKE4Sn8fAW0keosAJCvvXA4AEKAyM8okGUcklUCrNpcL7PGHSlcLQ6TxB5MEd1@OHAM615ktenWIthLrEPsAGX04HzSWCtnJ0P1H93N4Rbz0GEPPO6w2PVUnxffF@/PjRe@w9Aw3/8eMnCJ3i0CccCkDoEwmFSAjDhXGI5AiSEE69Jzlw3KP35d7FbPkfcbNZeHRaSZqPuz8@jj4GuXvWuUbw1Q@qDjQbQIfwBfB4/ZkMDvr9nrMFVDTcF@3aN2zODog0NARlSAmWpuomqtYKxad6tnWR8dAzQ6dlqU8rML4@TaEHw1zGsyc/TErc7BBsqKqZIQ2G4wl0CYCcuRxlqjPo8zD/kKaSWSazH1nBgr1pNDc1D@VuENQlwaSc0Wgj63gitGkbqAeBL2/PiURdna41nEEJ/EhFnsOoB9vyO9NVPOw7qTGcOnMmq1vxSRw/xRPNME8NeR6FVPt2HekApjAgnnyGYTJHDQMBDEkmo@tIBzJNUOIJaVjvu5FfWOYFx69no1vjyDbGfenvZ1ojZwnyvj2fDRnKzNBwJQnv9kyvnXwJnGmg9gXZSsRCgiyGTWsVxmojEaPsCwoN3oPYk5eyVvsyUCbogJAlvkrgdMqmsAVjWQWmLqgiGWQ1Yru5qXVHeaA8dkeO7o5Snk1KZGNS7reDPdtYiFCDoExUrDY3oScw@uI7KGAa/zanKBkj8rMD@oaitykktzHti@RnD8CxY1tB18ATfcySSzxNxOadqiJFWBAwMkoQZMAqSeHoBrng8WIfPbsj3w4xfUGcwdSR7ksKDn8DLJROEUix35feAwW@YNLd6x4wfdbfxzYQrtEb4wjtMN6c6aYsDJzrf/@DATTA2@YZcUuY8vCTdeAJ@IabKiS@21pOVnxDfva3LIEZz2SJI2wgoW@h5Dk8LeXkdWA/aqyaUSg04nRo3KXbuCCc@AeG2a/ImU25LsizgeBe9xdCWLxrgtm5FWlKagRXbE@S8fSd7K8MSDs/ntbroIQGBIu93CIJm9a220WwuCFUjt7SSKApv4NO185Dm/UVMGjMmf2Ll1S@1a6Shr/7uXK8K2RMnOuzAkxHub70Dh8xGYn3JNvuMNgECYkyN7GDTzi4v7J2dXRpOATTy7m@BwZ2NkyFNI4X6AW5vKtk8EhgNwYOfQWfLtu/74G4C8TrwHuAUE2Z/PwSwSOiwEPvwKTiRc3QFoukV0yVuf4Sm2mjXy5BuEAy0oKCyfCBABPFg@56FrxZPtW09/NjK4HkT6f357ZXWgkCXhVFQfhWr4WRR5pycigy2Aq@q4Rds3YT2gM65uYcGLwyZ4CAmA6bhTk0C/n5mtDiwYSfyZy@CX1FZDfkuIsd782XN3k0iVdlyZFM9@Y9bfh6prFBg9fSyc8mK757y98BGPd4oA6tQ/s7tMqbeM76jhx9h4Kyp4t4Qr4lGGH1Pd7x6gJ/3@29I3Uu2L/7B63VXqq@Q/2EZCIZMGF8m33Af0tc8eIn@dnPxcleqkxe3ht/jK5VVR8JioEiYQabOApZsYchW5bt@WurXHtfpg1JVg3UJL9f4wVMCgzD/t0vzdtskzglxI/sPrYO78@2lygywKEs@X2ncTl5qMqJ1JDm4OddCZjpItbyzvV7NdxaQ7HsNzXU2uBRFda5vqvaJ/D/LeEga7E6XqLYCn7Fjtqnzpyp7fsVhDkBXnfcX7kSkyI5w7Q9k3uvAXR@tOCW7vVvMXq8x1139NCWxFwGew5nSKcgYOq2Cf23KS329dIG36ej3qBNfqsSW407kQXQ2OT3TZOiCMP@whwsw3y/xhLlmTAT9mqQWn8sgNh8TXd8P1GMU41DZ@2DBubhbdo11MqZDH4X1Xg8x3dfVTicLEEn/6Y1s1fVaGBja3jyXIdAHQfeZhwqM22ncbd415gpja9zbqS5PVsd7BCJU36pRkp922baMcMNgXzfM9mLUxWmvOoUbAjlO9rfQUqWiezfHcQkZoN5LOEVK/2reI/Rei0T7FewR6BVpYkRwste36d4Iu/N1QlwOg2zMUUwl/j3PW7vU6R9VZV/SeuAPh1I2EwD4xP7K3yrld7YPs6yNtqsShh4haMvvrceYY81zsQRuIcnye82dB2qZJLB4Xta@c064FdGra1VwW/NH2HEJos@hs674ffobeDOzYZT4eRXCXZXxGg38DVk6XD0e@wjzTV6yaIrXqi1l2Y3DhcHr/SPtgROSYOQwY@EqUBuv2Lxc4PxzHAv7wJZKv7uSQ7TZNn0nXyaBB1ewb87y8BbJpGpKoJBm5w@FPBcRRY4sEbt2PeUrLsau5e55Sk3FErflKzNkgPe8OR1aSe4f/Hh2N6D4CHbN9SIPQ1UlYmwNNzrfmN5yUN7zqZfxbavk/N4ZfObvTpM712B/obNp4zUkTISRjrpGeu79/oGSKRpu2R9rRJA/4gzJniH11FImllBoWe0NdsbGdt8llVZ/h4@Y9VoK0pV3b/8WsQ@VgPI@ovwLrk@JDiXb67UwQhO2EWG8vd60UiYwUBlqKaqCSFyt5feiu3B9tVxqisJ@uC7bKTX@whvi3Q2jYiT0Xof2gg63lEQJ@mOL4yxdjg7KCu8LpBdaXeXEh3gvfLZdCZzpqqHEYHz@bhAwO@n7Ex4ljpUAMyFIi4/2A/A9iYykCwZJoGVRHR/jw6/WMfMMfuCMshz7EGPjzZWsiNdtDTiq9Ows94fco@ZQ28o5D30PijHiPESUEGGScNeUG4HTpTIxaZzU3WkcFPieoDDbk1PbP8GmMtjF6IRpwxkAbVh1CMrHKpu79LbriAtvKz93/564HhWgZoz0FQywEgcKtgbUJ0KI3XxyS7XKT2raRz2zMI4FiO8botLD@WzyFhIJqh14lClLlC71Eo5/hmOvyLc1LFy26LCblQ84GKvIdNuNJuagSrYEuQUvM7lVopX5dlUQQtpYI6MMEzMFV4g/h/rHTsIYTDF1HG/GgRRGQ0EvKg4wISRQUVW1QnZisSU/Le/tr1SIFHCIoTDbvHEKW2rRIQHSuIKwvPqDKh2kawEXXVAfJjJoNhm2F4D@RfseD/iRxxxlwFJDLnOIrgY22Ekn22iUBF5sVMl3oI@kUTfYbZx3rlnHjO/RlNa@O9/QPu/OHzz/CqUZA1PELkgJy9YrraTGUjepHqR59DyONXC7nvEW20tVI6rrg@HSXO5zh9T4vlH5E5YEOcPsqeqYL2NXeoUA/oH3PoJarvTZA59M9s4CDVNFMeepzDechCyfQWJExV2ZMBZDi30MxphWQnxiI0zcGczRMa@M9NMzt0Uim7v29EFoT8ja9jzSDgSzZDqHD5lTs9ISBcGKnZlu//xwYowoQcrWXykDZc5Dw/Wr5jILXBPBZV1@AONO1CxWvhyGD5jfv7ZgNm6x/PiPbH3MaGXH36pl@vFZivbajeBmy92ZQ9Kqj7lNpoCy4Imczx0H5n4CAJbdEkwvq091hpkfQfgPh865NApdjL2@9cJa1CH1Z6Q59AOrkFgAN/O/Y3s@/Ibwlb6WwBHM4kScrQoqhNBcmTGa2xr0KArW7hdcHefgc52OYJ3l/eoQsIjD8oAl0LApe/kEXpbS7sFP5EIaMZvM@rrOPahAF5tIN4CYCaty8L1tdPtyu2t/MvfQ401GNf@rjUmOL5aYwzxtRoD4CYbyVHKlivtRnE3E4jTxiEcTCMdu/uLpG/ZrqW2dKmOG6OrmWDgGdmeSZy80a0GmkuG1JcFIm8iHhnAhCfdkWxlGVi7IKzIwigrG6DJBwNQTf2liTUbqPQwcV@wfRhCCvIcALPC64E2iDwUhjUyb93ZQHMtYKbL/2RnPiRwBLNB7XG/fRDo3/6zf2W73D6YEP5DJyxC@J/a4R9pzKC3boM2jWvWYLZ0ynVkwHBpV3zKWVt1wiMWHhElZSYgaQocnBOGYHCb2E19N3h89x3gJzQCMBOrXqxtSXmC/ujDTl/HNI0NDDxVDZMtcMGCdgBlTXzAnmfYBRoGCDoRT8RYGogMzV2EIclGGNJshH7/McgaNZe0zE99Hp2eniKPwXOykEmc2IykD7kfo56f1oQeAixl2yL3CPJAlk0OSDtzsvkOuQDrx1lxl/OyXvR4AmaG3S4wUvlIAED8OFpx@OGBoVB1WAWNrgiWSdT50rWxwMBRiC@PYDvCu4hCgMjGjT11X8vuZmcVe5xsSXN4uxk8XQzWxGDHnn2ic/8jejAflEfHYRuBwPzlHkFSIPxHe7y419KTfes/7Hvt/Ytrgz43FRXvtpeAWuSL0JEozSb8Wz3F46ACenG/@BlQQk@AnsUL0ljVjGy@WL6s1Ztv/F8JpPc1mBd5z04DD6Fw8P5xHfC@knqXqbkS3bzOlVxWblO1WbTCEJuVq9dk7ivtNaXvlN61t7Xflk0S3hTEMt@LmMwNQyWyuPsW@yaV3gLM29tub0r1@b@83D@enj0oB2@K/3nfowEH4SMsXBB6MMiDAV60R@eU3c36Fn6sywi7nl8Rz@bBl7Xfm32/iX7fg3X9kNjGjdV1C8AurJEzeiDMaWUmy1T4HYcBqHuYtosiPpw2YS69oGtcUllM6qZAnnqz8LhNDXLq8vZ5NseVb82kmj09JS76nAIzE13ibWiDKGh7Ekv8yWEaUzY3Mx@YTeHFIjLBW5LJDKiK9SbmQCJLJpzu@hiuU5rCVAq1XHqw4ti4pYIiw@6WI6ibLPVPuMy9hdaOb1/zWA0bmiyZPuwqaoXxJBFq4/PjCrCnsoA9TU/Tj45bK3K9TwPEgbU@A37VVQ1tJuYFwQ01YG6GCjNADmIgoMvZFOBEcmkIeJQQUFUNQWbgo9cl4h5K8Tl1CE8HcSg9PBKsgTSEkcbnD4JK@hXLblxfOX8AJtRe0MM2q87x7uw2Y36Ru@4Wx7h7LiwpA8Hy4Uczjh8xdyDeu@jOvX7PGxkgPsOOA/HgtfOwqyw40@m1G8fbVwohnV4rgt2@k06HRwaFHRNhXgElNk29AkEYQ33ilNOQb0a8rw0URuTW9@BTgoap@1HoDI9nC6SgQIDMSOBCEsKI5BRJSJLx@qIPP7PkozPQzjjWUAb4spI0dM@Gw48QJoX40SFeU8iDuYFn434KDE7IckzQwgAMf8eYogXMvTBF9vWQFEvhBQEdoPYmk448HJEOCLwgtUZnP6CNNtj0QJur6fSx0xq76jCNQCxO92gMQLtHzbkWJ/DX8S4DrmElBlB5mGpKoFA@XwmKAv3VBzIzhd6JuBkIme4Pus/TBjfPYpESDmwSLxx3NSB09xmtoveLrII9c0ifkHntyQuM@z894IFfdIb@Jf0P6DB98sV3KGeWNBhj/jPf4SjDBqJHgcChcuQ7VLA58sMPeDr8cgjWzlPYE/ZYABQ6lP0nIM9gHWUOlZND7tR3OMhEjkgOuA0E/F8gw68NOvzlkHuhD38AayIIMbrdO32Hhh93ByYcZl@APtxDDukgyMwXnwd5yNOwuPhDKRDANIQPnzABv6YfmgEyrjw0aTLzPnGMXHo4ddXIrq2ybok3T/faDHSij9caPU7cju1diScXePsRrT1p@@yj3//@gE3AJOpTIupTP0WiH48O0MFnD33k0T1fHgpz7z0nRsLPj/VJvX7rf/CBRHoP8jUPG/OgHxE6oqkD@oj5OUnTP/30E1if6P4sfBZ@9N@HvI/3PussmTwKJlJHwc9e1p5Ew4SMZf2@SMRPo4cmekhy3FEgFvmsnEiSpBmDAXzVEX5gECyxDJaSD/DxsXWvNx71Nn/EDwx8@vQR/sg/fNa3@PcjiXGiCcjbz0c/8j1b1MGZ9d2fJ/jWciTYoVk2AibG6oBl2YMl@XvCYZb9gJ/3Tnz8/AH4IATI5/j4M5ncIE8y5VFVcoNGAB5H6gEMh5aA@ghZIfyhDvgW1@IQ/u/jv4aJ/zoT/IcaPP7LTfAfdfDrTCbwSz/h8JMbog5@Ov0p83f4kHoAD2FCcnB29vjyEgjdh388CZyc4C/@h87sBk/Ixw4BEY@BUOD0/vQ0fHZmnYUez@6pgy/UgfVCHUQ8IHkPR9RBxjptEErvC2cOzc/OHLsC4dPQ4329AnZ0Kxg5DR1EStl8MNJs5w5YuItvbnFiFN82itlCrQ3Q9Uox2yyelzvFdh3ijcens8@fA2Hg/ufw2SNQYv0qcBbImKaJ7p6Owuirn6c9IfuWOiicWW06dArEVpyYBikm9AB3D34o7Gfq4P7g3vcp8inCyMycYSfs5Fqt2f@WFaslap/xTa0GyZLFjFWdGTEjdgCShhihzSyZpcVM1Ro7gKAAf8wUghIjWsyQURiFZdfovv4/ranXNRVQqZDNtBgTY2VEuA5rtWtAJkLBY/iTGIaxgE6LmcM/IyMi9uyPTwyptp95eKDukecnAZRBmPWGGW844fVKj/GE9vzlJZJ4viemQjz9eC9YkvnoQUHv08N9Op32Pp4c0MbDA23rR08k5jnBIC8vT0@FbCv79ETjlRPr9DDwORD6DJ/MWeDUuXw6GJydfHo4DmEBDyMi5eGnAxozPHz68YHy@hbdbhd/u4v5wg6RgB330F2ndsmHdgMQA5/5O7l3A9Y@EfH57uOPX178fv@HB@@J166dz4cEMIp9HvbBiogo4vETazkNQw0bxQZNIu4/O0vE4T6R8od8DEm2szx4NE178ITJ7DtM/Fgymayuc0sCFIPR7sHD6U8PnvvIYyaTjpPoeCidQKoeSkf9Hr//R/b01Ckj4odoj9fyqLoXfXnZ/vN9eTn1kY8f//n9ONL5PfP7INkfhzvri8869Z36cBxE4VxfXs5wkMB9gdC9z//of3mx4@DX5z@1cZ75gXN4ieHv8V81kKEh78HLAbZSFBSL@339peCPJXypQNr5y3yECvg8UW8U6uXxct77@89H0aNk7P7T49Hjke/0KHz0cPa4Mwb4vQcI5NuVxwx7gPlGHYRPGh424vFi@TzBewWqLIRldYii6ZNdYfA@@Y5ef1JsOnAU@Hx/lE7bZR8d/fwRuhKgg8I88DkA@UU@dHp2uhaqNUbLfwawX5DDZAi/fAE5sxPB6PE5uwEPDxZD@qgfnfQzh18OuJcTgh@9eLwnO/JK8Pu8J2S7yPPFc8jp9@yj58Vz@KX/gq3DI9ZPjJB47OTkKGaHkykIs0d@ewU0zsCdG4YUweB40ptPDrA4eYHnfqhVpi8MJQUswh0mBeLxOB2BX@tXiWLEok7wtoq9h@MJeewOhFJpgu8AGUaagglIH1p@gZIMjKiyzOlIFcWPdjzMpFBfEMCYFWQZrwfiiQbY2/JgAZPbj9QBKB8wagwBPtM6J8wEYTGbLYT1Jy8Zx9wY@cYwUcaf3/3mz/4hfP8avn9sX//436fj@Pd3v/lf/rff/sVfQeR/ge9/hu9/@t1v/uUf2F9y/1/h@39vxf1X57sFZ38pwPVPfvebP/m3v/vNP/1z@P4b5/vnr7@//dP/aP//P84fDv7Vb//0v@If5@Yf/jH1N//hL/H/n/yHv/nPf4n///f/9W/@w7/4m3/y70jgX9mB//ff/Hv7Fwr/sz/67b/8x1CnP8XhfwRh@EeBkP0JOAB/iCN/PmTAoEMPP29D/kyzMFIgeivyD9HPD9gtkN1AAv5//TPNwGDG2JBrnNuQf/S73/zzfwuxP39GEOdA/mM3uyM0O5A7dEJBfwiQf7EF8IcU2KLw/xH@Nh@LiiBkx2xFWxbF2qGPO8CIxFtHr9Q9jo9HQYjfxDuY3uTASTgtzu7kcpXOhobtnLtDjUVFY7uZXyWDsbk/Ge/mfPq8A/2R1HdfWTbgJ5L@cW9huIwjl19v85NskJ9U7ONbI/uT9dnCO/LWLvW72PCHes3a12B74lxOWtuorW@Ft1A4OHfKt@wm3wG025OUtVP0Foz1Cvu@@y2ka4zUhpD1rbWWrk1RlA1vB611pZwPRSVRuw4/jfL5RWvr2ipm8xdUAuVq1cKrS9wBiqNKsdRa3ybtVDdrfI2iV6xUXt86l546QzyH9TE5@sAihxOFT09ZljprFlsQ0aohNsKEqbNbZIVRvX5jeDwqhYeBjyieDAbD4TD84GuQfMg1fPijC8K@b7YfUNd4MyPN2r4lEs4BIV1I4910GD0WCnFm6OMTMGba@5FwwVE4qEvDkYnMhboGMAwDrMa1OenakmubsktdwGg1xc984/NGTDyLlkTEUGE8tkUi6VQ8lY5GUsFUOhWLs4l4PMhGgmwylUwzQZg/p9hEKp5mg6lYOhqLxdJB4Fc8naQOBGUgiTQNEyjW40EkICk8fojxFD8NqoZHZ9TBQBAlRfiALN/A/@Fg4EagWQp5oqkHBnlo2sMmKLzbeGRlPJEooEdRBlSmh/KsEI8OmHwqysBkrY9vcqlkNhH1eJ5ICnzyjMczwDdJJlXKJT0eAd/EUwyTzHk8Ir4plfJMqeTx1Owb/PF4lu4Nw0BBI3xXTDDYldwj4Zt81oYb45tIChfl8UzsFPtm6t4kAUzBN9EoRoA8nuc1Ooxct4tKkVymfcMwubzHM7NrkYI/j6dF8EXhLwWZsnZSjFQwR5IYfOvx5O2bGEF37mLAN0V8k3JuSnYKBgR0Mtz1ZY6feDxDCA51sFI8HovEzgQQeQhht0rF5DweHm74JadAPnFkCqvsMjvMwSefexpaw6F1zuMUqTUb7nyKJSdl/DoFf0jKpDWz9qdMl7Ohm2TVnI@OU5T@8u1nhVOe302Rt1Jqy9qg1sIfkjIcugnD2vpDUvZ@cIqoOmD28gyeMD@JYI17NghICrnKluU5AaGmcPdCS5//C5mG@pAhrQTo/j4mOIN5VvzTLOVJJD3HR3D1fPJEIWj5EOMFy9njffB4/Pfpx0@eZNxz7P30KeT9gf2EPMm059iTTHqQ/8QTgb4Z93gSKAJCfwfGpjAMedEnz4kumDNdQZGTF0zBKsOcEErQsw9fuSD@7fu/OGD9kxe8zA1kPvtWgUAQvv5PmGKYMMK82H@8BBPdf/JC06dYc7B40YSmqDOcKWOvjAMgSKybZCuXtXZAMCsOhxF8QyEKp2sZmxE@T9qHwBwWJfh98JDZgr1c6fN6kxGv1@89ASQfkWdLpfpPCLHIZqrP5YwHeAGcScPk1qm@Lx2CqRcKpYH0NyTpk2PD5HS8fk1KPEaeRNqDo/HZd2m3sM/BEBs8PurHT8/@B8qeCiRY6uCFGuCHH2NpdJI@watJMEc9PXPyXKFlchi42CL5hDr0YqK90R1T44D8HmJr8iAUVWPqweHhIXVw2jrzRD218NMp7SxFndFkDerh7CSWyeO1BjA2ww9Ppx9/@ZIczhw@@@wupJ3hpcI3n1iM0gXsaTXAx@fZSwipOObrEBkHgOYk8Lf5QMlUBpBSJ3iW6TnQcIfh5SVeqkQPdkVPf31A1hhQ/Yvr@TJTyObc8TXeivFxx03yiPr9I/L/uirJX1LR0BlZy8YiiqClX5rpH5M/pn68btfatdJn5jh1nHp4cJozyHpZL2kqZwntMwxlUqNIHRg/@9U4@2vl8uTgWPNGY14wqx8yB3bt2aT/4CySDBvc8uDR8Rv1xZJYYuGeTDwjLDoQu7ufxc7NfErWFqGo1D8YDIdS5B9c//TzIU17vTA9ODy7/@UMfSKLrAePiV@HTu3/U/hB@ZpNoCcR9/ixN67x49OPTwcIJp/IE4nj3hSgkT293J4M@6wj5ccjBf6EI4P8CQK5VY5OzyDKgAjnXsAQgv@IpumbCFgQ6XQilTigfk/TX9vJhtT11o4oCLoxm@7b28nq0jWH972U9f4OBK5nK0GHq3smnmtqIGxr4M1LbGxsxzn2x1YUOUpyN25p0Nh/DsdSFA5J5KhSJGIV5cPLKybxg0JH@CBP7Cbsp75QHwDXjDeJ6x38nFDUB@wDhm99LlwQ/WCYfuwfw/ipDx8cZWuYYcN8wshxJicyxJ5QLxRmDzcYGAhvuxF3F9u3mMMeVapmP@cjL5GdySCjiW01EbdgXO4WwUdItKmA2hwhUiKhHFfOLv6DDdafiZiUUrlShDwog0Syfevk9uh9fGQTqd5H0e8UjhiIwlgwOOEUAceAgA4ifQS3f4odmHkfgQwgFqeLZBsYoMCKDBJKgkh0Mt7j20fIjtGLvKwagNgu3WfXAB09OcU6dXDHMFwJYCGuHRkfyECnD/mg03r47Iv7Rz/64rpJ@nAqOkWRjR@ngwsawz5tlWTkpwNbcMhZWA6bCTb2MQhNe2K72/nWcE7MhlEv1JEZnJ7YTaWdUFc@3v8FbxOe/Hr6ww/8j9r99PHEP82Y@BoITGG4mvgkG@TIzEwzIB7avfR4YoKKkB4zU/@VD9/DSAgj@wsl2sw2/E7doOZKBmjBrgSGP7i6V0K/Vh6DpXslACTPgkd3mVWQyzBBC75Shg3KwecM69QDyjQzq4Bywp3CF@9Y7sx0YegOcCc7UTjLxCdnVvfcYwb4IUPGQKAElQE6jXs5EHj0Q@EyJL7NeCL/8AMXkM@sEzkU8mOoH6OfSvcmBB4DGXx/7ONOrU@r@xnkP/bBNQPFyH4gHvI5vH5Z0w70nQCP7TbdkG7TaGHyLCBvmskc3X06ujvKfPy4urdC08egzf5jZiMNmHgLE3@y5SrqO7rzo1csIUuePs@vpONfhY8M5AlKYEQd3QW1rZw2hUd3kKLB@OlQ/YL1JTkE0t0NxxLmuDfaZ2aRU3XImjo5q9Ig5/OaA@zoDXmzBi9JDrjtoa9JMEXk8KmSQaSoSogjEDjNOZQWJz5Ynz5RbtGO7x2UjJVLH2bJeKpJziTU8forOeDYfmLqW/p1nxp2de563tcs3xURzDGjia3uSlQT6XCGzt9jEKwGvjAvJ7bGsj0uQdkQ7QEwRHtguBDWIphJjp5wIDNOIrSW20CQC@sJ0X4sCB/KZGD9BOpt0/NBhdhkQGfeQ4YUHGeIbgJ5kiCEpFNSHgSgq1AfoBKYBlwH6RGdgSJDP/yAnNvTDExsk3gswGAYbhxgMdAbSqHw76AUcGAqxyCjWB@SQoC2DzgF@wnvFBT7uxXkuPn7IENgHLS9/cPE2983Uwz7IRfMN79NBm6LDx/GgUzMIQj@ibkO@SHt5fcHznB/DMbKdb3dKjaus034hQlHanPu7fH6hNQ35yJq@LzDvqQQr1iea7BC75IHEwaMRxApdYDPPx6gy3YFRSLVQhA/6A6sP7CXgWBAPV5jEgxygJgRVvUhvZAmEr17gDo@q5Y44JLj2kPuwbWYHDI4y5tHbzZP3hh4mQcGc@fp3J2js6eCYTjHPYbcE7TJKeHkIaQpfpYGeqFzPCTxbXLdM4gzEN56CBIXM10aSuRY5JGNYCc/OcnPtLOT/kHhYx0HnMlhiabSKYY5RkwQB1g3EHEDUTcQcwNxN5BwA0k3kHIDaSfAuphZGzNMDqPRxCaY3ARTm2B6HYwxm@AGQyyyCUY3wdgmGN8EN6XF1qUlUgQvOnC5SbquoOM0NpZy0/BTdopJIuOAhn0dGQNCI28gIXvsTSSUl9qNTKYZp6AyXcNAkUhicw/ax4XN@GyqgjYdQbtk@86JhLGKsidLRGCLug5aqWjhc2xB6PzHCD9KQFGgdhEvCxwYA4IJVkqmBPIv@I/tR@z05fHmcQKMIcOu7yE7PucR8rDkSGZbfPYkR/Yl29gie7HZjzOiNWO2nsVwiLSpPN4ZaW2MsZ24bawfsYLFHH0HImJD4DbYfXjDLbOlz/YWGf16kTsI9xb5higbb3xfLswbH0GecbOS8Z9gy7jl2XaKQFobzADn/H0iA68aFD9rmfnCHnt@95s//z/Q737zJ3@FfvsXf/X//af/GYf/I/75P8FmQZE1wB//Cf751/jnX@Cfv8A/f7qVicBHjz2//fO/hNv/6d@h3/7DP7GT/vm/9QRja0SQgqM2Of/sH@Gff4x//i9PML4G/LM/sgFxFk/whdoxrXwA9cf/BSEoDWNZI/vzv0bIEwADw@dI3r3dxx@3nsyyEazZcE9Cj6/T7V9@pGO2M/6AB/A6d@zmLoAbwL@FXOfwgfKbvgfmjO0RjLU0z/Ej/PSNE6Ua2P7hsQmjGuEhyNtiAEaPs7zghdr/j@gYeQMYBqLJI6YZW4c79Xfq7dmkYtiAhwbq8BmtDioc9q8pgektBfJNZgJLI4ynLWRGytoy4vC3il9Y4Q4gHleyJNPH@imnLDc3THqQc@43/G@mulho8TBkP6JJzt@nnAdJ2K0Cd9TNq2aDUl7HwJRx89DWdlYSIUw1aBLItuY3Ziy@IVwIvka3aTmn2xRrpVcdBn/6YGJOtjXSuqAM8ni@AYs57cD7scUV3YW36XUA7pnj6OPOI2D7gD23t7ceaiuOwTKkD3wEw1albJWxTmJ3kyJbSZGtJKDZxkl0TTwSeUUDGTiwXtx93NHOtqWidrNthAv3HLcdMBkwF7TXFYOiPDNGmbeoiUbeVXZvkW@hZB8zTj95UIjOOUMe/5sMgHM3T@Z1W@5HzbyBedtQ@3Nibu/E7LTW@5h28mx1CsI96jWX1i3Hpve13G6BX0HNPga@s6AI83csKPSdBSXi3y7odbPivDvo3@fvt9WOqybWGn6DzO74BzsDFB4a/xxEb6OOMMU6Cfr8MOXJOlOe/kJFvj0HvEM87Z5ss3Oqu7513g2exFRVU7CXBz5rKkw5VGwFb70VZt8bnpyXsAwVVReM7Uc7JfsxGcWLHy7m1aECo1oQn7AjOa8swBvP9okTu@PKemRzrNC8/aIZjNpmFLY8n54kRTKfnsD4lEX/hoH4NszjZxe8FH5DDYS28vvWpm1N86n4pDDT/22cxN61s7UkfuKraU6iFwrJIpjQ8YIMky804vgJftcSYQmuInnQElukfdPnx0wcqVN1KCgqfq4a536FvrzBjQniNI3QEkRcEPFbFDmTaB8f5PxO1qtfnBVdRXycf50/sotghxlBpL/mMeasvqe4p3eLs7O55TV/Ob3NbXqbX6dXlHTDfE0zicSrPfj6y4qO@jYYAHBDRvTbZASdoxTekLNDyjoavzjBzvDdJA4Eg4fhD1OaBdCsAx4WQT6C6zsD7taEd97j/9cb0M1e/N7mI8Zscwn6ZlrEth@ZohnkzBmFF3wAXvZj3fO2uLVoF76zLGeiQ2Z4QeQhikvBj8BAx9Q0QTHW@70u4m/IPPaIeSP3xE0mYyfuoUmfB9Ek8n4TFZ4GgswthYHPgQxu4XVr3BC4AdFX31dxrOiI0lPtt2X4mCC7Y4qRRxUJ0PE7IsMF537/@2Jlg0hr6SGbcYTC8vv8Iwt3r1UzXgTN2Hsgqg4a9ICcUUJOhtGW2tJ@vFm2X9Ll6FF7/LFbsoqf@v4mQ4AP9iuY2OCmWP/X1GfDt67Sd4wIa9jwbpXxE4wuRvwM4ds2/GUs@nZNySrDOlPGbeUd6@S9Fpe@1uJbUuHKpG2VfJ9IfkvovlvmtkTNRrZRYflfNoS8wZznZJnnfdsY7ZivtpiqvNEJOA63mKq8M6o87VGo65xE05n4pPOMbV/4KQmCZbjO4dqBK0YIc9AnW6DcumG71l3yIilTTtuyWpyYex7boltc9G/vI25BUW4YL@S@rMvk3y2Tf1Mmv1PmugfsFrkFRPE7RTqtgJvna00gC6L5jnbGSXjmDpevqW34KCqn473XL17JeywFkXfuPQaF7BW8x0UfKGXvwHtcIAHDe9wkgYn3@AoCm77l/dl77HYLDKDDLQl8xvGOCsf3vPc47/O/UOTVjG65Ye/xuk0B5pN9SzjyYi@v9p1df3W9qioIQduoDCIsMQZcVFyt@8cg@TLwT0Cdg78g8WMGRY4IMJ6A7AwaWyOGXQ4MG2Hy7jffvuHj2F2actY3NmsokB7IbC2qYCmZEX3kPfDuKiObMJxKFh/hCgRivXm8nyLEvpmZfYscp3SQUNLIu@UT7oWJPTDwkfR7AN5exJE3@d322kVhN@D30Ykzv0fnG3Lc4ghF2BnAv4cszNSfvF@pFG7rV4dI2a2/3UJv1whwI4ZcELuVCNotnQ42HLZNSWGaqu0KCUnFu33Sdh78cTollt5X2YhWcHrmO8kk2qkZVgzbnd//teps5cOk7aggnHjPPNq9bD0uEF2Mkza6bstStTsfkLClcwbk/AcBi23BCRI4W90EyVjx3jDk5rWLJJprV01C5jB@WG7GmXbpm30Z/AjdL5u@ujnBBAcaMYKtnOtSbP2q/gL7XbXtd9egdpnwqoB9hvX@ofStef3VUfYV5fKm2LcNiBODqODfaxytS9iwHGYHW5b512TtjYmPX35jG/l2oWvsr6x9l23rOcE3@PZ6bmHjwlaCPt@NnOCF2UnkfUa9tUjkedg1WsK4JAePXfE1pZuqfZ1Wu@L7mhin4DEaLr@4gfXdBt5uPIyPVEB/xXK7l@OXCZJ9inXfxmvqWzsX9q6Dir3E1keibUWCuif@a2sXLYioPTUKtWqlB4NuMpn0v92KwL0W8m7Gceqr2wTraUskiM@/Ia84xr4TI1U3Pz4onrcuZSQCjAGO7NvY4uf0cb@jy7b0@au@C/ls2C2OOrgmm27A7WglbOpweMiWHL7ahy/7jjgHiWveAr@DZLaGd42wdOANnacnMnw9PWHnnKcnZxTDTbPeRvr9gfPupcjWe4oPdr2Z3nmFPF4AmE3tt@Q6C3DO8RG2H8oBfiP1@gX061wzxZRcZwe8PoS3qNaeEb4o67dfZO3G2O@bBkn1RWJ4ChuJ42eP7VwYGi98EtdKp5yPtqGDz0Y1NFVxXkg9sV9aTk5qNdylV0L2TFlwxA3ELoU8Mr1Fke2Q5e6LkXfMkuOu7Rf6coq9hOzyJoiEYZjs@ETSMOWYSJp9PNra9cPwk0yEYOKjBTzuy8IUv@cVZHfPavK1BK0yKknDIQgS7Zwobju4tPCrX0OqGMq7x34coA55W69zrKTjE0aOdHXWgYGdvp1zWwwUSYA1lQ4CZzdfYCx2k0H4bBaGOGkRKPgm4ZK0g6ngVt6PvqV/98q6Hz/G99H3hFvWfvRS0vHp4XNO2eKz80Tm1tK0s2lJ9MDWzqV7BBHlHBmVIfuUYeyjpvk8Bx73YCYctN0mOJl3TzTx4bN0jqkPClE82AMM8bZvDRi4CjbayPaaf@2SqqBfoWiEvAoRyiNWKikWcNg7ezvYIQ2yYmJt7z5HwXh@NfD8Cm8mUh8OsC60ZQ3nd0UZh8kBkxtZRh8ddPaGCu7Kdhdwb@JbN1GYanzYU/BHnycAWAIev2cHE8A7ux8fbM37NisoRf/v6dYg0S2p2Wy2NWX1xnl2mB1lGz24zzGVQHccK9J08UIeZAvl/vJcTbbmYoRp9W5y/WignhxYmnQxzV9oRUqK9aaBu6iVvoit4vloPsszt@J5RYwl87firSFkZSFNz8eTm4HQ0PqsbkhX1etqY0WX2jed4c1YvOt2x0mlSWmNu9zwxhJuUl1l3mmny8aN0MlXzUl1bM7YZS3ZTbQXipHrtHKjy2V5MbHKCbUnxfM3QrIjahcLfhnX@Is2dTdvjRLNi@UkzU4Hy2zeGPSSgQDdy@eGqQt@cCdeNvNXg6Ee78cnzTQXnU8vRW05urpQnivjfHPOB7RxqZyYU0q9PF8Ise6kL18od41Op1/I1RcT1rjTBuNY93pm9lN6IhqdZYXROBYvz0w9Vcllr5JmIVvulOTbjnm37KTqlHlhtpLtSz4tB@Y1k4/OCm3aYDrWpXTVXCQuIi31QrmUy@P65Hx2Xpe12aQQk2qtaUwf3pb6aiRycdOcX/QqlB677PZSjXEkVeAtnr6Kq@o02kpXK/q1Ncs914Runm/mhH6CycVvi@z4urbka/NKo9Gta932NGlcsfJdiRlTtVu@mc1NSpVpim1Vl@XUebk5y@fL1rwfEYdqdjboRq9vE4tKVSh3b@joBTczrwNSvibT48tLY9lpX5Vvq8YddOvrSykmLq1cJ6eLz4W8cd2o0FV9MmrGxspA6ySlvMpf1ssxszzJXiy6d@lybiKI9f5EnbS6cndmSoUxXaKW@clNuy8sStJqwRVjlc4NPS42eDOZHUab9FgU@xO5ZqyG55XVsDnrDwfp2jlTEJ6vBrlOvFHU2OuSEasqS6rXyonSqnEjspN6@qJ81y9mpWslnq8LWv38Ym5FIj1JrC/iK9a6HZdiksXHmEotd3sduLmMNAKVQC5XV6O1IRUplM67w/hVQC0JK7oics/JfECfzWJWYYbf7FtpK7I@jctMqtQKjJKG3k1fXy/6Rvm2ke/y8ip1dz2ZJO4a1O28bKh6JHVZyqbp@oTRz7lxtXyXlJRSbJE7l4vpcnfVTpnFykxOXVSGhcuGXmhN@dt0cdhcLifD1KVQr0yylJAqNBrj/rDTt3pNo75krmP8uB8onherz0Pox51mKXLZziWGs0a0c1VQ5vVWKbBSb7sVLV@dsMV6apZoJaNTam5dprJNU5G0wvl1OnEzkyrFbGHYzrOqINw@81fshGu2lkzKSOo3pdsbzQiYrb4a649y0eXNdY/u3BlG/EKi7qxuopyd6PzVwDIvjWRLiai1G4a9EattOT7vSs@9ujrOTumr9u2K7i9WJatu8mZzosYHyfjk3DKe9dWVfkWlemNOblfzamXMJ6560ipJx1ml1cuL13zvMsJk28OLa6F0MR@u2sI0Mr54nl3wHG/Us73@uZyYW1pAjKbmFapV7d4Ok8/PTF@o9tJSdtJu1MtmpMXRs16zEn@u9AyjxLfLUi4mKbNCrnc@mebvllzLsFazVqIvi8u6HmGKlFXtXXf4sTo0SsYdP17dlu6U61kkcVsbi0lzMGGnElvpiEyyqjUChUBdPu8Pl4nOTJjzYBlqN2WNzWXH4xpVY6fJeW6ZNkzl3Liq9vOXWSmbraQiN1okeTHJn19YA6nT7lQvBpwau@vno4laf8hEBrlqcViPTYfJejUZq@SpVn9502AHhZTEjjg5P75cxrR0JZJL0J1F4@Jm3BopVTmf7VpiLsq31EWyy4lKW1glkvQ1ExiP0pdKlonVE1TbLJjtSmkRDShX5etIfbnkb/vcLMqJzz0jwPdWo1WtI3CqPKo8N9hWZ1bJS@NxJ5HjW0wt12RmK2PBaZU6lS7UFbZQsealxajZZQytcKGl@lZ1kK/Xhb42iGpiv5a1RGbe7d7d3LRryvT2ZnrRSPZrqwE3jndMsZGoWSb1DCZPZ15pl/pWQTTEcWP@rJxbs9sOHWufTyvtwTwwTt/15lHptsZUqrmOyM3KN8Ok2a5a2vWlLMr0NFIb0tSiXV@tTCGrFquL654ldlarrJQznlnriuYq5@XCrRlIF0vZQq3V5HS5VjuvFLLcdHG9qNwmA8KqeT2IS5PnO6quKHJEv2vKyRwTNSLteGGV58fnzOw8N21dttKsxrYvOtfXV@xI5qd8slcrJLrXfDebvbxaXopcp17X6lftFlULKLd3dy261pIrabFSbrTUeHmuX3e7SW6hZm84phyb9hcVK7e4ns260/RloGcKXFRdCQLbWMgVWrgA2UlRwmxez1frxjLyvBo/D@cF9baTzmrniWx@KQ7mwnzFZAvzAG2UrMUgIWmpSKtnnYs9/no4vGrkRlFtrrUS@Th1mRavlU4/P7pOL4Wri0qnNDOF5qAfkwIGo41bN9m20eaX0jmfGM3bRk@Gzidq8VYunzbku0LqSpcCTIrPUXz3mqvTlVH8tno5UBd567qzLMCUI8WKdSauLpXOLDVRLq6M3FX3@SqVGrb7FxMoeDa6G/FSO5Ab9IUbUa5Sd7dXnUmxPuvQ45vb62S9fRFIraL6@TOvjs659LK1qjGMIKaH8/LMimoVPnWeuqrx8qVVbbRFYZhoRm7kc2VFFZTkiMmK7GK@UOjAMp5LFYdirl1V9EKbv0gKap2jaat7Z9a6t6mryDlzwzSnCyZiXC9oRuwp0rJX7fUiAyo3N660bpOdFwMXZrbXHDf4c5mudhvllbqsFCNGO1vNi1ezxVKrLCU9esdXzvNynZdYMEviiWFLb09WuXmf6opWJZ9LJe8iFyBBhiGnF70YJ/CGNrTGdOV6diFb49mkowemFt0I3PWseHrUGRk0X6m0quVFUY@rl8ZYoRIJPnLR1bWk0XieLst5szDqtOVYPt0Z9msXPfq6JV6lb/LNu6QQr9PlZyHdbSYYvhLv8jTbUKdzE0YkfjihKktmoPOyoHPJWe05XpzNAoPlfGYGtLvk@VWqO5zk2TnPBaLZvvrMWZ1LmZGqSWFo1LqL@W2pCxai0pm3Fap019aiV9KF2Lzo1K4nbD3bWJl0Lt3lb2PDns6KijhvRM34ZVkYJnmxULybjAsX5ecy0xOfmQUr6zc30dIFSyXFQM5UBzLdudFulFWEE7K9Wup6MVjlp6OqKFyUIwW910gMmlecXIRhVHquMFqndF65G/TlES2qSq3ZYBjqLhEpdm8bz@x8cFNftVTrQh9eZuty9FYsK2r9tsMWbnS6msyVbvLjxl1@mUrUdbkvtIapljINnEdVnssqlQSVFOZCrtOl24IUZZPWqs9NBJq9604mqQt6lTBWdFYxFuPUcJXun0/Z7l1VPW8tJ/T51Lqr527ZmRBg2TqvUTfmqh4/P@8Grpbn7fJQbpdFnuamy7FxkZsJl4v@TSIbSGlMK1AcdEZWpT7UukU62e@n2GY02o2Zz4P60ripUp1C5SKaLCxNSyxOZlUrdaFlE82l1b6JxSZ3Y6uWaiYacYudq5NiTisN47R6ayQVq3UxLOWEongtGterPj@lEqtZtVxKFQNxgevVe3eMWKSfmwPZHA3F1tVttJmg@fhFrb64uytk6WlSHBfL8jmMiQvu2lo2x71J/6ZmRCVKrfUC5cQqsWre3VQHSr17eT3qL4bJZF2/6IzTs1VPa0iNgLZql/vqeaE@lQurWxC4RCMdH7flYrsr3RYaTI0yE93sAmxwNleRlkO6HGeuRIW5tKbn6dtpNzHpTTr5eaNnTcaJZjKuzoRV0uw@x2dCO9m7nDZpvt9bjAKRc0ptrpa3xZuYXqkutIpZV4UrJhWp3E3a0@KsHZjmr0p9M99ltH6kW1nMAvk4WAWp6046Uu1fjXPlyfmNcXETSVOtkrScpcbnifNAHQaT2diopTpyRJ7TXVruLObCZMpw1QLX0a1@u1QZVAeRFK0FpOTCvEo8X/bqd5ypxRSaMpaJwYILXBTBgihIvXgz0DE1ZgpzEeZ2Hr1ShtGIodw2m7yZV5OTdjQtxEp6R1E7ljruRKSb8@RkwUtXYyonrAYxud3oDqrWajFIT2IDrjlvZ0u3SjeaV7SRZehsIn0V6XDP9akerZlavdLmc8rNlOPERcCSc4VrvTmnBsNqdtAtPc/EeSdWy8ayy9sBE5vdzcessrot9iLjej87EheNbmzVWERzg3NWaUwlbapHaKbVUYqTlNW@EK6oy1VRWI5SN7l6J9a@GqcnUXk4adaZ5aQmifzdnTFjy71h5YYdlOOd3E16ciEaWSHZTouXY9qq9mt3ifxAiDFUYFSe0pF8hY9eFm8D5iUvx5@lFVs1V2lRWVbbUr85nGe1ymDcnlVzF3SOjczPrdo0etGgozMuN00VrvSeLlNCMZ612rXrhDG6y5qdmFqPzFPaXV0a3kYG9RHHT5lECnTw9aB/t2xnG7lFpVe9aBpZZbgSAvriSjkvl0o5hboQu9Vn45lTxVk21q5VejfPN1l92Ir3TaPMWs8CvVwqtcs8zy972bIxqXYum0o5yUwHuevkzWhQUdpqXYpeUXw6OblN0kqTv5wxQqyejZWeO@f8c3meaKgTxeRbxTvWrDZA2ZXj7ZrWW0xX@REjWtFY8daoDQfaHfTW8YqKzC4avUFDHCvWonFpdq6i0yY76SzkSULhtECsmK7VOHYYxZOw@K2qTFX5amjeNqvzK52mR6vETNDOhSuJqkS0YbbcSFxGuPPzXiHdZqfPFSGSuo7NsotIrXEdUOKCVigPpzKTnzTGwo0EU4Zuoj6@ZJpVqT28m@Vv08smter1xbRy2V2oV/nJojCZj1ttKwrTq1anYhjNxq05KM8j/cuk3K@NBq1CKX/D5znOSNaUfLE20Wad/nRxEYtT41L0dnydvJSGiUmyLCx7VzMtXb9clfOji1igp1ymzB5nys81efxc7Ztm/zkpdZo3l3Q3l@QV5nmZNG9HXdqgLlLT4nlMSK7KIzbZVqbz2WxQayhqeVm/uQY2JyPR1nmfzmrdm7rZGVwI/O1FGyz9S1UoN28vteb57cVgNlAoOQrim6f1q/OKUbotTO7YRbmx7EtsYFK7WtTiybiY7gfm8Wl1NCvE493k9LI6LxU0PWFdg9Yf1pf1itCoXlPs9LpXnAQuRZZN6derzjzWyAq3if71QlzE4oWspYxSqTZj3Vye8zepvlZeTNuX7PCGXtylJ8aUa3ONLK@KNSr3rEWXBcssMvHiVeLi9kYYJxaD4ixSzi6a3XLCTFfFbjf2vGgsJkK1xIota76I1Eu1G1OJxa3Ozd3kClohTvFD66aYFK5jwoCRVnd5vaT2lTaXZehLOrJod24C6lB5rgqBST1SimqJImPVOZgZ3@Vml4NEvz2Wu@e5i/SIGsT4YqBlJMp3iefb52tJvx0HklNQOSmxMb@5BpOkb7ZbMetGTPfYVSef6nL90ootXtHZ2MXFLF2ORC4r6UqPMprxKUjL8yJye1mQIzf1Tis2CxSqBWswat61G/nFdequx07r3eb8Ek/GojSzEGvjRntZLVltSUgUJ42imKMC5ZuFUUtrYqPQKep0fSCWYuPJxXnpXJhd8TOrqASYYbm9nD/PpkLq8lrmBF0pNcxRlo/2UpOoxZe17PNVh1pecMVLNp/qpPSJxF@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@jdlPPFbCtxeTWaxK56rJGjc9ejcTNCjSv5yYA2zdRMakolo3iuF6zR3eRmOusvkvOK0VspV9xMGk5ZkdMm3YqSTGRvOs/xGhMtXtPFu5WsRJJxK00NeHFwScuNyW03JRUv6J48ggl0AeR/cns903lRN0bpLtT8eqUk8@3asKNfyKM6UCj3ZxovTtPSZCRE76gG3UyVkl35SuRrvcY02etLt63LaFKcWTB/7RVWV2KBhlZv95qjGXObKILpGos9l7uj6c282jEa8UKnVanHqM5zoyCy5WKl0rkzB2y1xgxLc7OdTF0UWX6am1SLy1w/V16U@Hb3IjAORFoDfl7qZOViZ8AZ1vKOSTN6VhxTiXHiOicWWHMR74h6LH85qkU5uaxatcuUNm3ULyO5y@KNqE50JneTdT@JzjI9leLLoZjNnnfKvfyQyt7kC@NIRzT4hhJYlAlYriRzv//FR4UIuq4QMGquSgNE3lPuHHNx8pWDJ8jJE/jx9p1zJ7Czz/ZBAqLzfDXQAuUEPW38hPCxXQjZ2wzjNxjgrcWT13uLIdY9ToBc8Dke6Ii8tUDc2Qj16DjzmoyPkvI1AsiOJ9lBwftg5PHkXxnH8AUagi5KYBN5os5HeOP/Jm2EI/icD3xcJ/N4srXl6WO3qcEEQpNxigj8DHp@hU9V@AEyki3gYq3k37etz5zs5AfiDE0hJ414QmEPyeqcioEx7aKwWxPHr89moMiBLO7G2lfeycTRbIpJpMn5HkgJmsHpffoxeMRnPEgwJU6ZGjN9MZgM1dFcRDLSxn2LX66eEYrHUBTKivxgn5bJJjI0OQ03Cb8plGac46Hs0yzJeUX4kCxy2iA@G9OLUGh9xNRH5CeBIP459py8kVJ0NHWl0D7kY3qfeMwoGeZkeq88niiBgN8MZMwAG/DhiB9Y/4k2czwR781H8tQ@fYSu3Ufr8RsLsO@vKqK6qvAj1Wsg8pLg7WdOyGFgbgeactp2f5oLvKnq2zEiliduutMR30bhXWLuVU5JdeHMpSbgrbv1qQQyfr06/vkwS8RO3qbjGn74gI/QOHF8J7Yr8IXSZn1Z4o@pD4SfeAscP05/fOwcCsMjLLcfPpA4yY60aUGS4cPJJ24qr2pLJ7Nkgzy5dTndQnnmw3ur/uD3QLpQfZDJJ/x@KR3AbBCbvTvgCFCTrVG/TRUOVwRlvQ@Kz/Hxn@BTTtBHN8098QfDY7kh5@48mUgip/TA5RQ5oOQMDOR3TpwgsfcSfuiNuBKcee2kD@PZVCP7z2GbXocj@JWYTxon6eucYWOG32bsQyxmhuQSjVsAB17weWxzzhS2m8ZtC@z4Rh6@wvXB@OrkDShAMM/p@hLrRvzwAcY3UEmeD/Y7V33IVG3HSpsMJy@pht9pamAcPqvaq3mPEfGDO4EosiV6spU6hlRc13eSp5A85czRO8kjjHtmvJesQzJ@E@s7yRIk289E7k9XId3e6X8HwMReniCuT6b6ZHKS7LMP9MBHgbzYCtuHAgGXsWsRQHbD2O2xmx85R6Ogj3br2MK2I17QP4lY2QBYpH1O58H3G2khqfgob58tF1tl2jxBX9A3C3OcI4HFT6QkULu4fP/RDn60RQD0P1Cl6G26W7jd2uuK7shPGIadIW5tYFYU/fzz1yhzBHFX/thHV/rsFsJ@uFs1tLm1wWO/KHLTrnamlZNpfx7n6Jht7eb6SGzq4XbKyEaF2H1r069FSRlAGYD443Y0dnnyo0@bmHvjER2vtceGj3a3@DYfI2@kB3tEkR4ZRP1NkP9@rnJY7iEnByNyf6Ms8Dlh3Mkbdhpr6NAu9BlAr7n5Ss74HZlxeukvrez31eYA6COdmvDmxFa0PJiGZw6Be8jj7Hbd1gk2skPvsR2PX4Ap7SKT3kFmn6f3BAjMU6ABj2yuGnfHREkJ28@kgp5nIrEgcTG3QV42bHKV1ffw6e@hc2HGOUP2DL8TbFcloT2seQO@rjfm19nrLveqeram31@5e/uhZu8nL6YRvZUnInWfYJQ8RgxaH9x0gl6@rYf@dpz5smm@HXvH8L2vK9xGdyXxe0Tw5R1Gf1PIdqsQeUQ7HMckEM3wjSGJHEK4f1DauNY/uTGu26Xdt9@1wDBVJ7vpmGYboZsAhvJ2rqBjc51tVKdz@uKT6Ro3wY0Vhl/FaUsFmOwn1LY6x9O5Ehm8t2PXR0cRjmyn4CfZsYWpu5RJomvbghns5gvzT7iZbSZjfkKfHqrqwOcaTI7BQDC4J3QAUNA@zmptVtnm5aZ4KM4xetHQOeXDHXdPIOajE0XGFYjAxqcjm5iIoyHpNie422zZN5JB3hRL0vFoBEW5Tx9gZ0Vb@6Dj1/EYem0CfdibydX4@EwycnKlo@fJSLyjHjx5TsGOobg57Kn1qQfHrxsCw5zBRHtzviVpg5c9qwz2GZ7O6ZZftqcu0okUxjbxutFdL0j/yZqa01MPLmYt8C@/P/hIzwyd7kv/f3HX25VGk@xfZz5FB28SSGAEk9x9rkafIKLOHgUXMMZj3ARh1LkBhsOAwN3ks@@tX1V3zwx/1L33xZ7nPHGY7q6qrq6urq7prhps@oMHMqpv5s6G8geSIG1bTca3hT9wULjcOPqitQmfy@ZDiCQmNFLA5g78aRZ1yHJGFNFMzpGYdHxoseQgDjCfG@/5D12y@iViyzCMZvzvnDYLRXcyHIdcohFx7Dr1K/gVx1Mt8i0ivWPQ5HxiOHGdLO4XyNu5nJUslMRAKiHIcS4B4gotWeFmvmUyGD8Qqs@TXl07keu3O/cgArL3S7ZTNFwsyb@dyAw9Yq2BFbi8Qo89iTIx5LOjQMHWSTTn39R9/C7hQd7wEVfIvd6nOHwgGCW9MBxCyHEUFO0/EQOE8S@arYNqo@Hq1DVyYh2n3OUcM64IcsA6TkRgj/HitDrCBcqgvEBnAVvw7cbAWf8yj4BWswlTYQp2Cq8Qj1B6UCjxr6Vu2Po5qc4s4etO@lcEXhZ1VI8h2VHgXdwsm2hWMM1M5QQrXjzJjXang0AQp34/JIorfq9HRAsvXsTswCM4YvC/s/ijK@C8tsRLeWGpvJAqd6VciIpruZ37UVxpO1kps/GPuN5vlYmr5Zdw7SrqtFfj6FJuOErQvfNY3cilTVoQV96zQylSaQs@pQoKiZK/rxh9KXmZamMF3JZfSbmW7y098pbKVN3Pafz46@gB8jkGg76yuCCl7iDo/SnuR1vCGlYhrJI0x3iz2Mmk1A4RrU4KpCZIiHna7u3GUN6VjMbhOZPZ@/Q542qX1J/ZRTIk59rSxFoxRxJcYpzvmHEzXkkIDxe/TIBgmBA0ZWbunmk8143nCbCo9dKgdUyk0PQEp64tTvFdHOv@hX/MZE8TZ@ptrC58IZTPpPNy0yLNIFa6LzOr2ZTWJuPRxJeXulOPrCIx7vkixNVKohZiB9q5h6awOH25D3IbTgbdl1ZPJBWF0RRLfLclmtNxhZIR33VDiMLfzj833zpH7T5ZhT1/psqwqdscEt9JXbYZ@9E4ojngUwdHKpoMh71Ax3VTU77OIf0sbX3EZYQYYsJocB0PF0Slfh5P@nIMNXJVHZCnuGcYF0STOySKhicYOY9Jtd4GBHLsOuXBnCMTcxi0Lbny4qsJ4rhCAfdo25cgQkZOZg97HmCluY65WCRdvZX5PRiTCUQdDznmIUKtbjvO3yZB52flSG0Vi38pFd@XEiwzruqi@/6D8hImkinYKpaKxY@lD45TCYdzudqY7eQA60MBAPPqBAv9F5JN/wE5iZ0yrRhcMSLTP/JHD37XdZyG32Uf8M2EOQJRnkS@RFHmOK94Q7YV4t2TuduP8oq2XfdQL/iL9Vli13Y4sEbewR2ioT/qB2O5aRQ@BF0w0Nybug17vXDKjmhcWRJ@oFHfHxNT3uZUmiSOS6tpYduFw8USN5BcgQP43YQPHEdas4Hs1ADh9/kCkIMgioCQRCZ51xOUEL5Orx30IU4rCECUpZgDhgDqWnfS8R@lwWEi/kUalO5YN@xMEJm3bUZmk7RfyHOFprs/Ckj7xgzmUeFmCdppgFvHXlM164eti3Kjquj5rFH/4h1UD9T@pWodV1WlfnbJyarUcf2EtEtTlWsH9LbWanj75606vciUm9QywwVOuXapql/PGtVmU9Ubyjs9O/EIGoFvlGstr9rMK69WOTmnxfoorwiCqtVb6sQ79VpUrVXPM1bTzInbqfqhOq02Ksf0s7zvnXitS8Z46LVqQHZI2MrqrNxoeZXzk3JDnZ03zurNqkLHnAOvWTkpe6fVA5fwE05V/VKttVTzuHxystDR@kWt2gDxqV7uV4nK8v5JlTFxPw@8RrXSQofipwoxjwg8yavmWbXi4aH6tUrdKTcu8xpos/q3c6pEheqgfFo@os452Se4QuNSOW9UT0E0caJ5vt9sea3zVlUd1esHzOtmtfHFq1SbO8o5qTeZYefNal4h3yajJhjELSqn5/3zpsd882otWjPOz1pevZajQb4gxhCVZWp6wAyu16S3xKR64xJQwQcegLy6OK7S@wZ4ytwqgwtN4lqllaxGCImJrWQ3Va16dOIdVWuVKorrAHPhNas5GjCviQoEE3gvyoT0nHuNcSK65JGE1TGSm@fhVN6hKh988UC5rk0S0PS0tDDbKsea5zSXN52Vn9we/YC3/JVPu0IeDxJfqR9UyeKT5CyZ@P05LTp/pD/epcpoobGF9FN/BeW16nvXv5ncfQ8GtyG25raZfMHuR3d5pCjKIdvpN@eRLMz6Qzk32Nj4/v1L@Tvtc5vfv@fyz2mZIuOpFjoK62O1crqPvbDd5W1@yreUZNTeax3rPS@Bl5O@ltfW@ZBTm5tdXzfD5UUANm4inZSAgHWhGflWY3ugEij5E3PaV8QZMxadRebzZhjRP4Nf8Q9ZGxIvSDnLuYXNTexhmQxkPlGWfkLCSUF0ZhA@BxDcMko38v2fd9liEh22/NpBlTNtuO6YtoF32dwTzW/8u4XmhcX2TCzumrKxYsLBmzDtEMyQf2mWKT0u7oh7lhXXHv/JGWoYERmFOUHFF1n16ZPsa2mO@KLiK8zt2FDinA7ktPzVu8Bmrrj1YWfh/bF9L3MLt86R24bWuytud81/jq@lAk2wANsvYkkwl0@qm5uJNmSVsT1pKyNW/T0qTYMuralYqu99XtYRIV/CBSfb02I8CmZJ6kkNHzXKp/vnh4ekOUHthz8@/uU/dxwdcX80/pqXv5fAg/yOzF2yoqcBmWlclJglFbJ7DpeS5SSy@2D0UBG5Fc2g8cs2mbQ2cqbYCJJfQ9xA6G6EDAMDJNnIIEnAKKNwP99/6Rh5XTkztQBkU13NoTf99owt/DaZSiwDHYmS2ZvzqM3wD2Db6W@muO2QFiAtYn5/OJ6T5NLmgvVe5tAEHOC9DV8rRhU3Y@R42DZnkIQx0JkchQF38PmXlu3EKJJdi4HGfOVh55ZExMtFKkySFk65RCjOwsjMYHkZ0JuvWt7o8VInB0IRUj2Ux01i46FtWTDJe8TnrCeGhny9t0tD9Pq1xfRJwZGa00SJ/z@dOiY5G5gUOdCgFgCbk0eWz7aEndCf3@TUP0RSEdUbcHa0xOrfJLmruqOh7JiQ6Pq3ySCjBFacUIZfTS0Ox1S5NFUsO1Ns@n/xg@H/G3myAv4n2nAS9JhbrIeDwcR/JicZqvCKdq/MlGBqTowljqnF3Ey@uozB/E4OzL3tmD6GN5MPS8QCPTpz8@JSUoplVzAAQg6/RnL@IoAvT@L7Nu2cPvPcfSFf@keDTn@YNQm5zFKxBPc6zzZX3hyRw4@cfMIvqgS6E@RX@cxxHllnYMNFWuxmrl5FGYHxrsQ6B53efMtODzvLWTTBhpKZ4bE4FfXUMpN/pk8YxatM15T@JlN0fbIv@zkEOYVSCt98ATEKhM8@JTus2UY490Doyn4j0gt7@ZVexZExklQgr8uqxeE5ovYt75mxFOlYGgjaAZSA86qrczbd@OMploueQOcYIjE0lX3FYUyARPsirRlhlG/OJa7zIju11LObEvJqqT8f/BwgrbAvLi5Tw01lgEqGYHXVaZuTQfWe1@9MjPwd2LqXxu8NOK5KR75XwjXHO3fCgp3@qyjmCFmcU1iXtA7FXGp3fuJlxshoMC0EM/rDuAq65yanEe0ZOGPdKqP/99oNAWRl4QysynwbWCfStixku6@M@YInmbv26RJP2s@8S50i4ugNDsxqMwgkw27CIc3l2cb0pcLq4PDpNllO06l7057024Pbdj/ozfnU6X@H94PNaDCJhu5w7mQymbQ3EIHAESKFaB/76iIYdMNppPZpOsCR1KydN8/Sjr@E56sini@l/ko41D5jdpbA3yJmUhTejmlo/B0113m2R7G7h/2E2tPCbq05XiAw1YgFiPD2rWV8VDtXR/7AH5E9eMZnLtVJ0PEHpD7ImOJTmNG9aBpUPwT2psauDmG7sGdnR/kBO3Wsb8/RCDS0PEQrS1ORCB7ptIrwzc9J1BM@QXe5w3G/usapdB8OdTQgOE1hbIqL83bSyzvI3XjhtY6xGZeNOftmaFkzvj74EsV06ouzljozag/Gc2KKs@i8IbKf8t24ioMBEURnPTt5U9dHWvIu3H69iLqKJOlaC/AKQlPVDx6QLI7dcM8ZIz5nq91mMd92dHzFvKSvM6ojNXpOPHp55Ax18@rjf6mWD9lVZ712h3ZYqjlB8/fvyQ7cD6Mxqp6WlSpulUqlQuk9XLTnzbLLEwH/mwxijuOdntUbLWKkDpFvBMOumWA@J@2S01jEjpKL3F3U/R/QyKYBqcytH8w92OAmkG9mRz5ZZLYzNPidNvy91MUobQ@zTxY@@XDEmcMQDopkKDUfnS1XIewBkvSxmgSqBPg8Jy/T6cdkcXHeG0o5oB@3@AHqeiRaPXwS/cGt@R3pAH/G75wPLg0xdgddHfq@sKf6ft92IBibFb4tFZyP7kLiM8s1caiShLzJv4GpRCzMJQF1fRyUiJBCoB89dEakYNoPJHcmJhYJDSunHI@bCeOEVYVhrUg5QFOkG/Ztbh2B6jg2opt@P4zmnVBt3NFeGdulaOj7XU53MBlKPH@UuzRVe6T@Jdbbdhzo39ko8uHHEWkM5FUhBTbpIQAsAvbdyLg5RjRIMkyMwNY99uYCiDrUHPNMQ9q17Iptcl7hY22OB65NY4q2OfBhTbQ@AjHM48sSUUUDxkPKTzzgecSU6vGALQbzQ0POKBQN0wWAJZ9m/XSBAY@@68elCiJmu5aAhTiBhhgJdiXPKUdW@gf6i8OjiHyWlT5S5@Y5y8zDAHkwZYMfqrsQ/6KyazgmH/p8/tC3FH1whri6BG@xZmm5JtWyWUASNbdWwCyshPl@NcyChqm/OHqDB466hlYsFtILCekckpIDI@LuH4VGf3JsuF4oX4ls7@964Q2SL9FcJ2z4M8/HA5t8zduoFKOTpTnHMcseH3rhMrVrmxadfnsmxnOR45uxFyAYxJPW1edahXRUvOooGzIN1a@dOAJw6quw4DA/@YQXHyjO/EeGMyoV0@H0Z@ZkGAso10qVzznK9CCrO5TT7OcfNrpwzhCj@/WJmwwSc8h2WAqcVLdHuAqUTWLJbauNYVs@SqFWBJWZRH3FPMBH4Az991ZlNYJCkliphKitepIS4zmy7xXtlGRYzAwtOrHW51@JqUcj6Ihm4RNJoqCy2dSIG51iYcrjklYhUHgv4BiTI@ElIzIb5C10XUJom7AnkCVT2xD@jKx//oTJIFgzWoeofikhc61ca@KvYszXRp@le7G29qKSW1Unoe8sFx6rbJht@bS28no9yKzDFhUzUaonWHcCH6RmnVkc3kTCMvbDB2OOpRl2ArYiFtiWUAfSNr9CNaSH3BCXX@iVk4iUrXu4qOCclE5PCUk28QtZwNUryZMmgHJOqhX4v27AcZouObHX1itJPT3s6yTCwjLj/phY2Mpm3B8TC6mcGPbHxcKkyrOs5faLcpEaCWEBzrxpe5RdFkkdZApmyVqzhVpM0Pw6GSrb72VXUJvQqtqV5iwt4pZFOjNGGgf/mcnAbOg4lilxJOZd2dG4jntLxlbnp9@1AX91760BvpdJLwkymotx7tFpg4HH6DqHjMy2AWls8bHoLVlfjgZywPQ3YgvzFgdJoe7u05dHU2DNqlLMLZs6Jjh8TPynlcQXloP0x@b79nL6cXt4SVON8zThqIvaGWfFB0XnCareJahK9y4xQmkWr4FUeBakwjMgbSYg6Yn9ntZLftwYIQ2a/xSIb9@WYfCfv5OJr2GQpu0G8JFikzVtz5@C@TJDksNHttpyaMk2iC24p2D8uQiD007e2489@uV9G06d//FH4WLSh7WcTcvKCoosVRvLZOVBFmttNud0PWMq8a7L/XlzH1hDb@PpkZYwuboxTqre228MG@mg7RZYPP9La/iXTwxrej4I4aldvt/NOP/idHDBCHFgyE2keJ@zGPwW@S7X9j73JKbPsttPuBxKhFo0SkoijPEfKw@zmhj9s8qwfxL/xkr8w3BINsjtSgK4fh9uXPFILKjc2HRc2JQ9a61Zud4s9ytpVy2kpnj@JHy91PUt6jruJdOkG/hTvTo/Bln3xYzA/8HSvjIysobIVyuJxHfWtnaLqMGkf@OPnOdMRWnh4o/sYdZLruNsbKhyp0OzVx@hR4J6zt7ma5QwUyEIkZoM4a6P5GwfJh@8K74I8GLdbjgdcG03AxTsouv77YGOlK4XtLsR3Ne2bh7ZG3G3hzEEgw4xOvITrq8fkpK46@sSHEh9hK07q8ceUg2cmop8jEmTJbZgdp7ec8rbNQaItTq41vaiIWFkB9/C3orlrO0ZMpxzq50nz7FuHjNYSIjXodQb0gXQj8vo9npmToaWlXZonsHKVeaQ9XA@wxyaP9cc@jdwcnFAncSzXt31Arj9pFJb3IQ7/ws)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- LNUSP (135) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/lnusp)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))

### Explanation

Bloated/Modular SNUSP code (Grass not shown):

```
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++. _++++._#/+.--.<!\
                               \                /
```

I use Bloated SNUSP `;` command (move memory pointer down) to distinguish it from Modular SNUSP. Bloated SNUSP will skip over `\` with `?` because data cell under pointer is zero.
Last `#` terminates Bloated SNUSP. Space and `d` are for Incident.

Added `x` on line 25 to destroy Cardinal pointer from Cubically code.
To fix Del|m|t I moved it to third line.
Note: removing `x` before `-----` on line 4 breaks Morse.

Refactorings: merged last LNUSP line with Wierd.

Comment: Is there any reason why the SNUSPs can't share the part with `@`?

Comment: @Potato44 Yes, it looks like it can be shared. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look at it.

Answer (score 6):

## 140. [Gaot++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Gaot%2B%2B), 6081 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBk
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOxMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g4O6O@0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>+.--._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWW/wwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x


7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002216 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6211 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille,
**139** in Core SNUSP,
**140** in Gaot++

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3nrZsvayn5cfxoShSokSRNEk99/FFBjNIJ@nGTE86HaST7tx7Mz2YANMfgh4M0I0OMMD01/4V52swmPsP7qwqknrYsvc@SWRLLFatWrVq1apVq6oWiz3OGP7udwf4g2qqvBzIqolMwTBRX5dmgh5EmSX6zElGNBSmKAyV1gfTiaCYxjF1gFiEJIWX@nCPTHUsKNJK0CE@hJCmqwOdmyBzyJlIMHhOEwykTk1taiJV3J8tjFB@oo6kAM45kZQBgJmCrumCSdIjCLUUmZv0@tyLlOiLAjUd0g2UE@QfJz@aiFcnE07pGwAZQyhXzeRL6RcY4giVVd0QMB5eMAwVRyYQWuQF/gVoEkA5XVJL6cr5iySWQedAOqfJwgJxPcPUOd6UVAUnsahRaTVqOzkIS2u62p/yuLrmUIBkzCJRkgWD4qEqZ0izGyaIA@gA6QLXt8AoUdURzoImYxlJiNc01JO5YZBHsgSwBSaBBMxRtIJ0eWighTYBDIY6EbbpMJAiCH1kaAIviRJPSkfCwhQUA4g3gkjix2guyTLqCzJk2JDE@wEZmhpbURYBQaqvUgg@vPaiAuu7QwFgFMFhgqABUzETVNwGwBGHF3Od0zQgEpjYAMJNaQKiJJluAwmcIWFhhSyGoPQJ/7S1GKuIU7ZriWYShzigd6oT3Iag47YJErxoKOgCoOTWguSZ65IJLMDsTaOawOmoqQuCd1ekd4qEwlRcgokrEiTNd3rqzlcLbmhGK0eQ00zqQA83ry8pDgVT6PDxBL4pl@uEyldy6MvhPQ5bEgxNrekezotSv0QGfX8vwHfB9uiB/kwBVgq4IiNa1UyaC2hAYMAEAmkOB3EoMAsFNXmrYHT6oi22hMuC6kNroKKC2n5SM36q67iXbpjKjaHSsqoMgJ9QWX2qYH4oKMZAE/AqdDI/EmbANVWx2kidEw43hxI0moGbZKtfWLqGMBS0DciezVGnXEOVpwQOchomFkDgCmTFGIsiaiORk2ScBdIxKotqXTCmsonzTJU@bnnQJUI/iBwyeLWPgSbqDIrjACmJgL402eqBhCgAhoZQSVVx0k//8i/7gwHgSfO8qvdtcW2jvsoTrcgRYkHVICywqsLJhCyA8@PSrexQwIyTpT5n4uKVpV0EIYKUOlench@pUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITcUqR@NOHGlt6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodQJ@z0Eq8QB0QmQlMpqaYQAEtj9wG/b3n07Hn08d7AYjzBr1HhzQ9OAGBCx6RKLhzvyc57fSOojNMzlClPqUtzaGqhFCARy4@pWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q1ifebxnkgpPihKSt/jBhnPQLlu7wmf4u@k44eTF7m3SwQsc4wF91bBw3tdFGgc0idm9ISTlKC2RO2AHdpKU41HzHGcHNyKxnx5GTezIg7IOILFUsXyAWooaMiCoHmYIOvFWgLD7a02TthX0Rc47AofSw8@94Hbt111ggFqulNR3Febkoq1lqwNp6CjgSmKoYH21rHo8hwIj4GVuAmDuR/1iFgTzQ@KhajEueDWBdQDPeqIEemRVo/D@QNYT9oYNj3Igdvt0EJ/qz@DLoAubRqvlLKszqFgQhsevkCDKLhwbgBNBJmtCqWtClklkpjdqo0V0CsYW09AiUBPgr6Aex2odlv0t@oI4OGQBQPYrL6ypYIm3BKw8NaQuOk3SBKhS01AS@hLxAtY9YAOEqxxBRcyJd3QADMGGzRMIBSN7na1Vz3N1Ol04BZ09Yp@t0Phym/3KaxvkCjMkcwpgyk3wJaUAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30ctghkQF7DA0aQ@rw88uyyVhij65bZWBdb7WePSJyWMnYtlRABp2KONsaRH1JB@0kL1@WDgCzF4W7fsAgOwT84HqDBMcQACETFgI/NUG5gSDPhxI/BNnF1CmWerTGopfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aEwMe/ZdiArS6yhMxpsoArhFX@OBMRajOtuJII2/HfE@Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNkhzQZC9r@CcqIq6Bykwco0Wg@ymWO0ABlkDG4MwfjnWF@msawtx3UTQZqA9oOeD/A1NUzOOYbiQzOG0FwRJoZv6smhWFSwstKkvJVO1wj1Z7YF6NqB/0k4JND/tSYsXFSJx6zYcGdQM7DDRQCkYwJ@mIHUet2iA4iTxWQy8leQiCpygsH5dAEiAgsAoj2gQlVwApdJYKrzHFSRdKQidzuVHLtxxXV4I4FxrvmTVCdZCqEPsA2zwZXTQXCJoK1v3E9XP7R3x1mMAMe/c7uBIlRTPF/fHjx/dx@4z0PAfP36C0CkOfcIhH4Q@kVCAhDBcEIdIDj8J4dQ7kgPHPbif7xzMC@8DbrYFHp1Wkubh7o6Pww9@7o61ryF89YKqA80G0AF8ATxubyqFg16v62wOFQ32RKv2dYuzfSINdUEZUMJCU3UTVaq5/GMt3bxIueipodOy1KMVGF8fJ9CDYS7j2pMfJiVOdgjWVdVMkQbD8QS6AED2HI4y1Sn0eZh/SBPJLJLZj6xgwd40mpOahXI3CGqSYFL2aLSRdTwR2rQN1IPAF7fnRKKuTtYazqAEfqgi12HYhW35nWkqHvbt1AhOndqT1K34OI6f4AlmkKcGPI8CqnW7jrQBExgQTzqDMJmjBj4fhiST0HWkDZkkKPFENKj3nMgvLPOM49ez0K1xZBvjvvS3M62RswS5oUwNDVeO8GzPdNqGj2HgvtoT5EUsEhBkMWguVkGsLmIRyrqgQP8tiD15qcVqXwbKhL4fWIgvEjidsihswhhWgikLKkkGWX3YbmZq3UHuKZfVgcO7o5NrkxLamJL77V/XNhYizCAgYxWry03oEYy96A4KmL6/zilKxpD87IC@ouh1CsltTHoi@dkDcGzbVNAl8AQfs@QSTw@xWaeqSBHmBIyMDgQZsEpSOLpOLnic2EfP7oi3Q0xPEKcwZaR7koLDXwELJBMEUuz1pLdAgS@YdOe6B0yf9vaxDYRr@MooQjuMN6e6KQt9@/rffr8PDfC6eYbcEqY6/HgdeAS@4aYKiG@2lp0V35Cf/S1LYEZTWeIIG0joayh5Dk9HOXkd2I8aq2QUCAw5HRp36TQuCCf@geH1HTmzKNcFedoXnOv@QgiLd00vK7ciTUiN4IrtSDKOvpH9heFo5cfTeV1WuT7BYi2zSMKmta12ERbcACpHb2kk0JDfQKdj36HNugoYMubU@sVLKV9rV0nD3/1cOd4VMibK9VgBpqFcT3qDj5iM2FuSbXUYbHoERJkbW8FHHNxfWas6ujQYgMllX98CA/sapkAaxwv0nFzeEQtnMEBkoOfew6nL1u9bIM6i8DrwFiBUVSY/P0f4iDjw0EOw7OAFzcAWm6QXjJW53hKbaMOfL0W4QDLKgpJJ8T4fE8YD7noGvFk61bS382MLgeRPJvfntlZZCQJeFUVB@FrPhdFHmnByINTfCr6piB2TdhPaAzriZhwYuzJngJCYNpuFGTQL@XlPcPGAwmNx2YTeEdsNOc5Cx1tz5U0eTeJVWTI00tzOzVsa8eUsY4MGr6OTn01WfPeav30w7PFgHViH9ndqlTfxfPUNOfoGJWVNFfFkfEswgupbvOPVOf6@aSYM1Zlg/e4fuFZ7qfoGFRSQiWTAZPF19j7/NXHFC5/kZz8Xx3upMnl5b/wxKquqPhQUA4WCDDZzFLJaD8O2LFtz12ax@rZMG5KsGqhBft/jBUwIDMP63S/N22yTOCXAD60@tg7vz7aXKDLIoTT5faNxOXmgyrHEgObg500JmOoi1vT29Vs13FpDsexXNdTa6FEV1r6@qdrH8P814SDrsDpentgKvmNL7VNn9rT27QrCvACvOe6vXIFJkJxB2prFvdUAOj@cc0vn@g8YPd7irjN6aEtiMoNNhzMkExAwdcuM/oeUFnm/tP636ahXaONfq8RW445lATQ2@X3VpCjEsD8zB8sw366xRHkqTIW9GqTaGwkgNu/pjm8nirGrcWive9DAPLxFu4Za2RPCb6Iaj@f47l2Fw8kSdPKvWjN7VY0GdraGJ9A1CNRw4HXGgTLVdhp3i3f1qVJ/n3NDzenZan@HSJzyczVS4us2044pbgjk@5bZnp@oMO1VJ2BDKN/Q/jZSskRk/e4gJjEbzCMJr1bp7@I9Rut1TLBfwR6BVpXGRgAveX2b4gm9NV8nwMkkzMgUwVzi37e4vU@R9lRV/jmtA/q0L2EzDYxP7KvwtVZ6ZfvYS9poszJh4FWOnvjWmoQ11tiTR@Aenii/2dA1qJJJBodvaeVXa4DvjFpbK4Jfm0PCiE0Wfgydd8Jv0VvHnZsNJoLxdwl2VsVoJ/AesmQw/C32keYYvWTBFS/SWsuyG2eLgxf6R1sCp6R@wOCHwkQgt@9Y/Fx/NDWcy5tACxV/9yQHabJk@kY@TYIOr@DfnSXgLZPIVBXBoE1OHwh4riILHFijVuxbStZZid3L3OKEGwiFr0rWZtkBb3byurQT3L8AcWztP/CQ7StqxJoGqspYWBrOdb@xvOShPaeTd7Ht6@Q8Xt38aq8O0ntXn79i8ylDdagMhaFOesb67q2@ARJpWm5Y71UC6B9yxhjv7toKSTNLKPCEtmZ7Q2Obz7Iqy9/CZ6waLUWpqvuXYPPYv6oPWX8W3iXXgwT78tXVOhjBCbvIUP5WLxoKUxioDNVUNSFA7t4ClfFaj/W7t0odSdD732QirVeNerLKYceBdyx3wOFcv2Udilf1/RbcOaeaYJS@Q569R0V8mtbb3obfdsaCOEm3XW@MtX/bQVHhdYFsgjubougAb81PJ1OZM1U9iAicx8P5fF4vZWXCE@OBAmAOFPEwwm4HlvOSgWTJMAmsJKK7O3T4ZXHMHLPPKIVcxy708GBhJRvg@YVGXIPqVta7Q@4hdegOBNyH7nvlGDFuAirIME/ZC8rtwIkSuVh0bqqOFG5CPB1w2KnpieVOYQyJx9KQU/rQRi0YaMmiiqpbTgGW50kTr6b/17/p245coFkNNJEMsEsHCnY@VCfCUJ1/ssq1S09rGocdwTCO@RAvF@PSA9k0MuaSCSMJ8d9S56hVaCZsdxDbPRJualifblFhNSoe47GTkmk1mkVNXxUssbALXudyKsWr8nSioLnUN4dGEDVA4wrE3WS9QQghDKaYOu7KfT8qor6A1zH7mDAyjsmqOiY7n5iS//o3lhMMJEpYhHDYKZ74wG2ViPDYTDxPeF6dAtUOkpWgqzaIBzMZdOkUm4gg1IIV70X8kCPeOSCJAcc3BRdj@adk0w0UyCM39uHEO94nkug5TNfP23fMQ@qXaEIL/@33ae8Xm2@uXwTirOHyIwfk5BnL1XYyA8mbVDdyHS5cdrWwtyBxjlsLle0R7MFh0lyOr8mEOBoSuRPmxNeEbOEqeKjAHnyKAf0Dbr0EtdVpUoeeqWWPBBomimJHVxjiOQhZronEZwv7TeAshwv0IxpiWQnwiI0ycGcxRMauOpNUxtmLCm9vF9I5oTclS@ezUDAUTpHqHD6mTs9ISBf6Kvacu/v@fhFiAveLeP6BNhzm3N8vfsGEboB7KqjJw@9o3IHyldyXw@AZ8@OPBrdELtez@8TaPoVefvilVqzlG810s9UAbj5blT0oqPqE22gKLAuazPHQfWTikghs0SXB@Lr2WGuQ9R2AezzokEOn2JfZ610nrEFtVrsCrkMruAYBm2E791ey78tvCFvprwFszSRKyNaiqEYEyZYZt7GtQf2ObOF2wd19Cjrb4QjezN6jCgmPXCgFXAoAl76RR@h1La0W/EQioBm/zqj3cexDAbzaQLwGwExal4Xra6Vbldtb@ed/ghprMK79Y2tMcLxbYwzxXo0BcJON5Ciki6VWPb@bCcRp438O1piOnyoQSd@yPFkt6VJtr0lHM8HAM7QcoTh5o1sNNJMMqScLRN5EPDLArIF0R7KDZmDtgrAiC6K0bIAm7/dBNfWWJtZsoNKDxGvCcp0IKMh1AMwKrgdaP3JRGNZIvfaeA801h8k1/4OV@ZDAEcwGtcfb916gf/qXf2l5@N6bEP4jOyxC@F9Y4e9pzKDXXooWjWvWYLa0izVkEJsLV3zCLbbqhEcsPCJKylRA0gQ4OCMMweAWsZv6bvB47trAT2gEYCZWvVjbkvIE/cGDfcyOaRobGHh2HCQ778IC2gGUNXE5e5pij2sYIOhYNBZhaSAyMHMQBiQLYUCzEHq9xyBr1EzSUj/0eHR6eopcBs/JQip2YjGSPuS@D7t@WBN6CLCUZYvcIcgDWTY5IO3MzuY55HysF2fFXc7NutHDCZgZVrvASOUhAQDx4mjF5ocLhkLVZhU0uiIsTKLOl46NBQaOQlyHBMvv3kEUAEQWbuwY/FJ2Nxu62NFlS5qD283g6mCwBgY7du0Tnbvv0b15rzzY/uEIBObXewRJgfAf73EaX0tP@rW7suelszGuDfrcUFS8yV8AapEnRIfCNBvzbvUUl40K6MX94kdACT0BehYvSCNVM9LZfPGyWmu8crclkO6XYG7kPjv13QeC/ruHdcD9QuodpmYKdKOcKTis3KZqs06GITaLZS/J3FfaS0rfKL1j7aS/LpskvCqIZb4VMZmOBgpkPfk19k0qvQWYtXb6XpXq8X55vns4PbtXDl4V/@O@JxEOgkdYuCB0b5DnENxoj84pOv4BTfz0mBF0HM5Crs1zNms3O@t@E/22w@z6WbSN16zjiYA9ZkNndF@Y0cpUlqngGz4KUPcgbRVFXEYtwhx6Qdc4pLKY1E2BPPVqrXObGmTX5fVjc7bn4JpJVWt6Sp4I4BSYmegSb0EbREFbk1jivg7TmKK5mfnAbAqvT5EJ3pJMZkBVrPdN@xJZpeF0x6VxndIQJlKg6dCDFcfGCxYUGfbuHELdZKl3wqXuFmjtb/eeg2zQ0GTJ9GDP1EUQTxKhNh4vrgB7KgvYsfU0@WB70SLH2dVH/GVrU@BXTdXQZmKeE5xQHeZmKDcF5CAGArqcTgBOJJe6gEcJAVXUAGQGProdIu6gFI9dh@CkH4XSg0Nh0ZcGMNJ4vH5QSb9g2Y2nLef1wYTaDXrYYtU53hDeZszP8g7e4hh3xwUlpS8sPPhJkOMHzB2Id887M7fX9UoGiIuy7a/cf@mr7CgLzrR77cbP94VCSCbXimC37ySTwaFBYX9ImFdAiQ1TL0EQxlCPOOE05JkSZ28DBRG59dx7FL9h6l4UOMPj2RwpyOcjMxK4kIQgIjlFEpJkvKTpwY9IeegUtDOONZQ@vqwkDd2xweADhEkhXnSI1xSyYG7g2biXAoMTshwTtDAAw98xpmgOcy9MkXU9JMVSeEFAB6i9yaQjD4akAwIvSK3R2Xdoow02PdDiajJ5bLfGrjpMIhCL0z0aA9DuUXOOxQn8tZ3agGtYiQFUFqaaEiiUz1eCokB/9YDMTKB3Im4KQqZ7/c5ju/7No1@khAOLxAvbSw4I3X0kLO/@IqtgzxzSJ2Ree/IM4/4P93jgF@2hf0n/Hh2kT754DuXUkgZjzHvmORymWF/4yOc7VI48hwo2R777Dk@Hnw/B2nkMuoKuBQAFDmXvCcgzWEepQ@XkkDv1HPZToSOSA259Pu8XyPBLgw5@OeSe6cPvwJrwQ4xu9U7PoeHF3YEJBtlnoA/3kEPaDzLzxeNCLvLQLS7@UPL5MA3Bw0dMwC/p@4aPjCv3DZrMvE9sI5ceTBw1smurrFvi1UPEFgPt6OO1Ro8Sb2drI@TRAd5@ImxP2j776He/O2BjMIn6FAt71E@h8MejA3Tw2UUfuXTXl/vczH3HiaHg00NtXKvdeO89IJHug2zVxUZc6HuEjmjqgD5ifozT9A8//ADWJ7o7C54FH7x3AffDnWdxFo8f@WOJI/9nN2tNomFCxrJeTyjkpdF9A93HOe7IFwl9Vk4kSdKMfh@@6hA/nwiWWApLyQf4eNia2x0Nuxvf4@cTPn36CH/kHz7rW/z7kcTY0QTk9eejF3meFtTB2eKbP4/wrWZIsE2zbAhMjNUBy7IHS/L3iMMs@wE/Vh77@PkD8EHwkc/x8WcyuUGueMKlquQGDQE8itQDGA4XAuohtAjgD3XANzn8h5o9/Fc38V97jP/qPP7LjPEfdfDLVMr3cz/B4KMTog5@OP0h9Y/4kFoAB2E6cnB29vD87AvcBb8/8Z2c4C/@h67sBE/IxwoBEQ@@gO/07vQ0eHa2OAs8nN1RB1@og8UzdRBygdzdH1EHqcVpnVB6lzuzaX6yZ9glCJ8GHu5qJbCim/7QaeAgVEhn/aFGK3PAwl10c4sTw/i2nk/nqi2ArpXy6Ub@vNjOt2oQbzw8nn3@7AsC7z8Hzx6AksUvfGe@lGma6PbxKIje/TzuCVm31EHubNGiA6dAbMmOqZNiAvdwd@@Fwn6kDu4O7jyfQp9CjMzMGHbMjstq1fpf4Eu1CgnSghmpOjNkhmwfJAwxQotZMssFM1GrbB@CAvwxEwhKjLhgBpFqrPqZURiFZdfY3v@fVNVyVQV8KmQzF4yJUTMiXAfVapkZQHDIjOBPYhhmAWQumBn8MzIiMs9@/8iQWnuZ@3vqDrl@EEATBFl3kHEHY2639BCNaU9fnkOxpztiJ0STD3fCQjIfXMjvfry/SyaT7oeTA9q4v6ct5egKRVwnGOT5@fExl26mHx9pvGyyOD30ffYFPsMndeY7tS@fDvpnJ5/ujwNYvi0ZDz4e0Kef7s8wyyF8Sv/svrJGBdeP95TbM@90Ovjbmc/mVogErLj7zjoV/3RoiLJC@GYOn9kb@XcDi9dC5vHcRR@@PHu93g/37hO3xSCPBwlgVHtc7P0iJKKQy0us7SQMVWwYG0SxqPfsLBaF@1jCG/AwJNnKcu/SNO3eFSSz9yBxvUml0rrOLQlQBEbLexenP9677kIPqVQySqKjgWQMqXogGfa6vN7v2dNTu4yQF6Jd7oVL1d3oy/P2n@fL86mHfLz4z@vFkfbvmdcDyd4o3C2@eBannlMPjoMonOvL8xkOErgvELrzeB@8z89WHPx6vKcWzjMv8A0vUfwT/qsGMjTkPng@wFaOgiJRr6e3FLyRmCfhS9p/qY9QAY8r7A5DvVxuzn139/kofBSP3H16OHo48pweBY/uzx52xhCv@wBBF3FEOsUeYL5RB8GTuosNudxYxE/wXoMqC0FZHaBw8mRXGNyPnqOXnwSb9B35Pt8dJZNW2UdHP36E3gjooDAXfA5AfpEHnZ6droVqjXHhPQPYL8hmMoSfv4CcWYlgNHns3YT7@wVDurkXnfRSh18OuOcTgh89u9wnO/JK8HvcJ2S7yfXFdcjpd@yD69l1@KX3jK3LI9ZLjJho5OTkKGKF4wkIs0deawU1ysCdE4YUweB4ohBODrA4uYHnXqhVqicMJAUsyh0m@aLRKB2C38UvYvnQgjrB2zLWHpAr4LI6EEokCb4DZBhJCiYwPWj5OYozMCLL@LECVRQ/WvEwE0M9QQBjWJBlvJ6IJypgr8v9OUyOP1IHoL/AKDIE@ExqnDAVhPl0OhfWn6xkHHMj5BnBRBt/fvr1H/z06//xp9/8yU@/@YOffvPnv/3Vn/8BfP8Gvn9iXf/kPySj@Pe3v/pf/ref/uo3EPlf4Puf4fuffvurf/P71pfc/x18/@@tuL@zv1tw1pcCXP/8t7/607/@7a/@xV/A99/Z3794@f3pz/6j9f//2H84@Juf/uzv8I998wd/Qv393/4a///p3/79f/41/v/f/9e//9t//ff//N@TwF9agf/33/0H6xcK//M//unf/CHU6c9w@J9BGP6RL2B9fDbAH@HIHw8ZsA/R/Y/bkD/SLIw9iN6K/CP04z12bGQ3kID/3/5IMzBGMhbkGuc25B//9lf/6q8h9sfPCOJsyD90stsytAO5QycU9EcA@VdbAH/0069//6e//h9@@vVf/vTrf06BmQv/H9FHKoTwFf9QrIX2IwktjqhoGOTUCbObcDhCwlH43Wdx4M2XT593oizcR/uACeAnkv5xrwGDyzhyaNtX2Ecn/14Mn9BnSIYxiwxbC/yLbyAGh4nKIxcnamEDknsLxr7fymnFWPdoK/tuPI7cyuhc9kVbCaRIBwjZyBZ2oWiD3q4G5VBmAS9eRVDIrh5FUXHUqsFPvXh@0dy6NvPp7AUVQ5lqJffiErWBoqiULzTXt3Er1ckaXaPo5kull7f2patOEc9h7UTOLViQk4WCp6csS5018k2IaFYRG2KC1NkNWgRRrXZtuFwqhZXiRxSN@/3BYBB@8NVPPuQaPPzeAWHfNoMPqDLeGkiylqeGhHNASBeSeG8adOlcIa4BPXx8xVR7OxIuOAoHdWkwNJE5V9cAhmGABbU2rhzDam1gdVCP4/D3536gBGH7Y74fYVplkLhXKfJrcOoChpQJfo4cn2Fi4qmyJCKGCuIBKBRKJqKJZDiU8CeSiUiUjUWjfjbkZ@OJeJLxwyQ5wcYS0STrT0SS4UgkkvRDM0aTcepAUPqSSNMwT2JdLkQCksLjByRP8ZOmanB4Rh30BVFShA9o4el7Pxz0nQg0TSBXOHHPIBdNu9gYhbcUjxYpVygM6FGYAeXlolwrxKMDJpsIMzAn6@GbTCKejoVdrkeSAp8s43L18U2cSRQycZdLwDfRBMPEMy6XiG8KhSxTKLhcVesGf1yupXPDMFDQEN/lYwx2UXdJ@CabtuBG@CaUwEW5XGMrxbqZODdxAFPwTTiMESCX62mNDiPXraISJJdp3TBMJutyTa1aJODP5WoSfGH4S0CmtJUUIRXMkCQG37pcWesmQtCdOxjwTR7fJOybgpWCAQGdDHc9mePHLtcAggMdTAmXa0FipwL0RAhhd03F5FwuHm74JadAPnFoCqv0Mj3IwCebeRwsBoPFOY9TpOZ0sPPJF@yU0csU/CEp4@Z0sT9lspwOnKRF1f7oOEXpLV9/Vjjl6c0UeSuluqz2q038ISmDgZMwqK4/JGXvB6eIqg1mrcHAvHjxKILJ7NogICnkKi8WrhMQagp3L7T0eL@Q6aYHGdJKAK3kYfxTmAxFP00TrljcdXwEV9cnVxiCCw9i3GDeutz3Lpf3LvnwyRWPuo7dnz4F3N@xn5ArnnQdu@JxF/KeuELQN6MuVwyFQOhvwSIUBgE3@uQ60QVzqisodPKMKVilmBNCCXry4Cvnx7897xcbrHfyjNeygcwnz8qXYv1o5f2EKYZZHcx/vcdLsKO9J880fYo1B4vXRmjqDOdJWavfAAcC66RYumWtHBDMfINBBN9AgMLpWsrig8eV9CAwWUUJfu9dxKK3liQ9bnc85HZ73SeA5CNybSl67wmhFVk89TiMcQErgDFJmIDatfckAzA9QoEkUP6KJH18bJicjteoSYnHyBVLunA0Pk4v6RT22R9g/cdHvejp2X9HWeZ6jKUOnqk@fqYykkQnyRO8ZgTzyNMzO88VWsYHvostkk@oQzcm2h3emVUfkN9DbOIdBMJqRD04PDykDk6bZ66wqxp8XK8VnNFkpen@7CSSyuJlALAAg/ePpx9//sIbzhw8@@wsl53h5cBXn0iE0gXsTdXHJ/JZ0/xEFPN1gIwDQHPi@4d8oGQqBUipEzwTdB1ouL/w8hIvR6J7q6Knvzwg6wCo9sXxbpkqZAPuuIy3WzzccYM8/X73gLy/rEjyl0Q4cEbWq7GEImjp50by@/j3ie/LrWqrWvjMHCeOE/f3dnP6WTfrJk1lL5R9hpFMquepA@NHrxplf6lcnhwca@5wxA128X3qwKo9G/cenIXiQYNbHjzYvqGeSBxLLNyTyWGIRQdiZ/cz37mZTcgKIhSV@L3@YCCFfq/8w4@HNO12g51@eHbn@wctDQUfDx5ivwycWv@n8IOyVYtAVyzq8mKPW@P7x@8fDxBMEJErFMW9yUcjawq4PWH1LI6U748U@BOODPInCORWOTo9gygDIux7AUMI3iOapq9DYEAkk7FE7ID6HU2/t1sNqevtG1EQdGM62bd/k9alMof3tpT1Hg4EytOVoMPVOWbPsTQQNjXwBiW2NbbjbPNjK4qcTrkbtzRo7COHYykKhyRy6ikSsYry4CUQk/g6oSN8Nih2BfZSX6gPgGvKm8S9Dn5OKOoD9vPCtx4Hzo@@M0wv9oFhvNSHD7auNcygYT5i5DiTHRlgT6hnCrOH6/cNhLfWiEuL5T/MYa8pVbMeH5KXyMpkkMHEMpqI6y8ud4vgIyRaVEBtjhApkVCOK2cV/8EC601FTEqhWMpDHpRCItmitXO79B4@BYpU76PotQtHDERhLBiccIqAY0BAB5Eegts7wU7KvIdA@hCL00Wy1QtQYET6CSV@JNoZ7/DtA2TH6EVeVg1AbJXusWqAjh7tYu06OEMYrgSwENeOjA9knNMHvN9uPXysxt2DF31xXCE9OBWdotDGV9PGBY1hHeBKMvKTviU45Hgtm80EG/vgh6Y9sVzqPGs4O2bDqGfqyPRPTqym0k6oKw/v/YK3Ak9@OfnuO/577W7ycOKdpEx89fkmMFyNPZIFcmSmJikQD@1OejgxQUVID6mJ98qD72EkhIH9mRItZhteu25QcyUFtGB3AcPrX90pgV8qD/7CneIDkqf@o9vUys@lGP8CvhIM97L/KcXa9YAyzdTKp5xwp/DFu5I77oowdPu4k50onGXskVOrO@4hBfyQIaPPV4DKAJ3GnezzPXihcBkSX2c8kb/7jvPJZ4sTORDwYqjvw58KdyYEHnwpfH/s4U4Xn1Z3U8h/7IFrCoqRvUA85LN5/bymHeg7AR5bbboh3aJxgclbAHmTVOro9tPR7VHq48fV3SIwefBb7D9mNtKAiV9g4k@23EE9R7de9IIlZFnS4/qFdPyL4JGBXH7J5wMm@7WtnBaFR7eQosH4aVP9jPUlOVfS2fHGEma7MFrHcJEDe8i6Nzn@0iBH/pp97MwNedMGL0k2uOWFr0kwceXwQZV@pKhKgCMQOM0@5xYn3i8@faKcom3/OigZK5cezN3xBJgcc6jjNVJyZrL1INbX9Os@Nezo3PW0r1G8zSOYYoZjW92VqCbS4Qydv8MgWA18YZ5PLI1leVWCsiHaA2CI9sBwAaxFMJNsPWFDpuxEaC2ngSAX1hOi9bQRPu/JwPoJ1Num54MKsciAzryHDMk/ShHdBPIkQQhJp6Q8CEBXoT5AJTANuA7SAzoDRYa@@w7Zt6cpmNfG8ViAwTDcyMdioFeUQuHfQCngwFSOQEaxPiSFAG0fcAr2Bd4pKPKPK8h25fdABt/Ib3n0B4lHv2eqGNaDLJhvXosM3BYfPox8qYhNEPwTcx3yQ9rz7w7s4f4YjJVyrdXM18vpBvzCfCOxOUr3eH3o6qujFjV8hGJPUojnK8/VWaF7yYMJA8ajiU/kwUcq99Flq4RCoUrOj5@fB9YfWItTMKAerzEJBjmbzAiq@oCeS2OJ3j2LHR9/S5xsycnvAecsXEwOGZzlzeM1m6drDLz4BIO5/dDvzmncE8Ew7BMkA86h3OTgcfKg0QQ/LwO90D5xkvgvOS4YxOEHbw/4iRuZLg0kctLy0EKwk58cDmha2Un/oPBJkX3O5LBEU8kEwxwjxo8DrBMIOYGwE4g4gagTiDmBuBNIOIGkHWAdzKyFGSaH4XBsE4xvgolNMLkORphNcIMhEtoEw5tgZBOMboKb0iLr0mIJghcdONwkXVfQcRobSThp@PE4xSSRUUDDvoyMAKGhV5CQPfIqEspL7EbGk4xdUJGuYqBQKLa5B@3jwKY8FlV@iw6/VbJ1Z0fCWEVZkyUisHldB62UX@CjcUHovMcIPy5AUaB2ES8LHBgDgglWSqoA8i94j63H6PTl8eaRAYwhxa7vITs@OhLysOSUZ0t89iSH9iVb2EJ7sVnPIaI1Y7aet7CJtKg83hlpLYyRnbhtrB@xgsUcfQMiZEHgNth9QMMps6lP9xYZfr/IHYR7i3xFlIU3ui8X5o2HIE85Wcn4T7ClnPIsO0UgrQ1mgH2kP5GBFw2Kn6dMfWGPXb/91V/8H@i3v/rT36Cf/uo3/99/@p9x@D/in/8TbBYUWgP8yZ/in3@Lf/41/vkr/PNnW5kIfPjY9dNf/Bpu/6d/j376gz@1kv7VX7v8kTUiSMFRm5x//s/wzx/in//L5Y@uAf/8jy1AnMXlf6Z2TCsPQP3Jf0EISsNY1sj@4m8QcvnAwPDYkndn9fGHraevLARrNtyR0MPLdOuXH@qY7YzX5wK89h27ufPhBvBuIdc5fEb9pu@BOWN5/WItzXP8ED9hY0epBrZ/eGzCqEZwAPI274PRYy8vuKH2/z06Rm4fhoFo8hhpytLhdv3ters2qRjW56KBOnzsq40Kh71rSmB6S4F8k5nA0gjiaQuZkbKWjNj8reB3YDgDiMuRLMn0sF7KLsvJDZMeZB8lDv@bqS4WWjwMWY9hkiP9KfthEXarwB1186LZoJSXMTBl3DyYtZ2VRAgTDZoEsq35jRmLbwgX/C/RbVrO7jb5auFFh8GfHpiY422NtC4ohVyur8BiTtvwXmxxhXfhLXptgDvmOPyw85jXPmDXzc2Ni9qKY7AM6X0PwbBVKUtlrJPY3aTQVlJoKwlotnASXRMNhV7QQAYOrBd3H2m0sm2pqN1sG@HCPcdpB0wGzAWtdUW/KE@NYeo1aqKRd5Xda@RbKNmHlN1P7hWic86Qy/sqA@DczZN62Zb7UTOvYF431P6cmNs7MTut9TamnTxbnYJwj3rJpXXLscl9Lbdb4Duo2QffNxYUYv6RBQW@saBY9OsFvWxWnHcH/dv8/bracdTEWsNvkFkd/2BngMJD41@A6G3UEaZYJ0GPF6Y8aXvK05uryLPnzHiIp50Dc3YOite3jtHBk5iKagrW8sBnTYUph4qt4K0Xzex7WZT9XpeBouqCsf34pmQ9CqO48QPEvDpQYFTz44N7JPstCHg73DoqYndcWY9sthWatd5dg1FbjMKW5@OjpEjm4yMYn7Lo3TAQ3wZ5/HyCm8IvvYHQVn7P2rStah4VH0Bmer@Ok9i7VramxI89Vc1OdEMhaQQTOl6QYfKFhhw/xq9vIizBVSQPU2KLtGd6vJiJQ3WiDgRFxc9O49wv0Bc3uDFBnKYRWvyI8yN@iyJ7Eu3h/ZzXznr1s7Oiq5CH867zh3YR7DDDj/SXPMac1fcU9/hmcVY2p7zGz6e3sU1v4316RUk3zJc0k0i82oOvP6/osGeDAQA3ZIS/TobfPi7hFTk7pKyj8bsYrAzfTGJfMHgY/jClaQBN2@BBEeTDv74z4G5NePst/r/fgE72/Lc2HzFmG0vQN5M8tv3IFM0gh8UovOAB8KIX657Xxa1FO/eNZdkTHTLD8yMXUVwKfswFOqamCYqx3u91EH9F5rGfziu5J847KStxD036zI/GobebKPfYF2RuKfQ9NqR/C69T47rA9Ym@@raKY0VHlJ5qvYDDw/jZHVOMPI5IgI7fEBnOP/N63xYrC0RaSw/ZjCMUFt/mH1m4e6ma8SJoytoDUXXQoAfkHBJy@ou21JbWI8yy9d4vW49a44/VkhX8ZPdXGQJ8sN7qxPo3xXrfU591z7pK3zAirGGDu1XGTyk6GPFzgq/b8Oex6Os1JasM60wpp5V3rJO3Wlx6r8W3pMKRScsq@TaR/JrQfbPMbYmahWyjwrI/bwh5hTnLyTLPe7YxWjHvtpiqvNIJOA63mKq8Mao87lGo65xE05n4APWUZV94KQmCRbjO4NqGK0YIc9BHS6CcumG71lnyIikTTtuyWuyYOx7boltc9G7vI25BUU4YL@Q@r8vk3yyTf1Umv1PmugfsFrkFRPE7RdqtgJvnvSaQBdF8QzvjJDxzh8t7ahs@isrpeO/1i1tyH0t@5J65j0EhuwX3cd4DStnddx/nSMBwHzdIYOw@voLApm@5f3QfO90CA@hwSwKfcbytwvE97z7OerzPFHnbo1Nu0H28blOA@WTdEo48W8urPXvXX12vqgqC3zIq/QhLjAEXFVfr7sFPvgz8E1D7cC9I/JhCoSMCjCcgO4PG1ohhlQPDRpC8Ts6zb/g4dpam7PWNzRoKpPtSW4sqWEqmRB@5D9y7ysgiDKeSxUe4AoFYbx7vpwixr2ZmXyPHLh0klDTybvmEe0FiD/Q9JP0OgLcXceRNfqe9dlFYDfhtdOLMb9H5ihynOEIRdgbw7iELM/UH9zuVwm394qAoq/W3W@j1GgFuxIADYrUSQbul08GGw7YpKUxTtV0hIal4t0/azoM/dqfE0vsiG9EKds98I5lE2zXDimG783vfq85WPkzajgrCiXfMg9XL1uMC0cU4aaPrtixVq/MBCVs6p0/OeBCw2ObsIIGz1I2fjBVvDUNOXqtIorl21SRkDuIH2qacaZW@2ZfBj7n9vOmrkxNMcKARI9jKuS7F0q/qz7DfVct@dwxqhwkvCthnWO8fSl@b1@@Osi8olzfFvm5AnOhHOe9e42hdwoblMDvYsszfk7VXJj5@r45l5FuFrrG/sPYdtq3nBF/h28u5hYULWwn6bDdyjBdmx6G3GfXaIpFnQcdoCeKSbDxWxdeUbqr2Pq1Wxfc1MU7BYzRcfnYD67sNvN14GB@pgP6C5VYvx@8nJPsU676N19S3di6sXQcVe4mtjz3bigR1T/zX1i5aEFF9rOeqlVIXBt14PO59vRWBey3k3Yzj1LvbBOtpS8iPz7ghb03GvhNDVTc/3iuu1y5lJAKMAY7s21jiZ/dxr63LtvT5i74L@SzYLY7auMabbsDtaCVs6nB4yJZsvlpnOnuOOBuJY94Cv/1ktoZ3jbB04A2dx0cyfD0@Yuecx0d7FMNNs95G@t2B/Vqn0Narjw92vZneeBs9XgCYTqwX79oLcPYREZYfygF@yfX6XfbrXFPFlBxnB7w@hLeo1p4RnjDrtd6N7cRYr7AGSfWEIngKG4ri54OtXBgaL3wS10q7nI@WoYPPPzU0VbHfcT223oNOTmM1nKVXQvZUmXPEDcQqhTzWvEWR5ZDl7IuR19aSU7StdwRzirWE7PDGj4RBkOz4hJIw5RhLmnUE2tr1w/CSTIRg4qMFPO7JwgS/OhZkd89qclmCVhkWpMEABIm2Dyq3HFya@G2yAVUMZJ2jPQ5Qm7wA2D460vYJI8e22uvAwE7PztksBgrFwJpK@oGzmy8wFrvJIHz@CkOctAgUfONwiVvBhH8r70fP0rt7ZZ2PF@P76HnELWs9Dynp@FDyGads8dl@THJradretCR6YGvn0jlmiLKPhUqRfcog9lHTPK4Dl3P4Eg5abhOczDunlnjweTnH1AeFKB7sAYZ4y7cGDFwFG21ke827dklV0C9QOETesgjlESuVFAs4rJ29HeyQBlkxsZZ3n61gXL/ou36BNxOpDwdYF1qyhvM7oozD5BDJjSyjjzY6a0MFd2WrCzg30a2bMEw1Puwp@KPH5QMsPpfXtYMJ4O3djw@W5n2dFZSi93d0sx/rFNR0Ot2csHr9PD1ID9P1LtxnmJKvM4rkaTp/IffTuWJvea7GmzMxxDS715le2FeL9xeadDHJXmh5Sop0J77b8CJ5EVlFs@FsmmduxPOSGIlnb8QbQ0jLQpKejcbXfaGu9VjdkK4q5Up9RRda1@3B9Ui87XRGcaVBafXbzOB6IVwnOsqs3UoWjWuhna2Y48rInLLLarwTa80VI9NuZoaXy@J8vCjG1K4UzV4L8baoXcz5ZVTjL1rU7aw5jDUuluMkO@kv01mj3437fHQ3mxkkLvj@rXjZyF71B3q0Fx03klx4NrkUteXw6kJ5Ko2yjRnv00aFYmxGKbXibC5EOuOefKHc1tvtXi5Tm49Z41brjyKd8tTsJfRYODxNC8NRJFqcmnqilElfxc1cutguyDdt83bZTtQo88JsxluXfFL2zaomH57mWrTBtBeX0lVjHrsINdUL5VIujmrj8@l5Tdam41xEqjYnEX1wU@ipodDFdWN20S1ReuSy003UR6FEjl/w9FVUVSfhZrJS0suLaeapKnSyfCMj9GJMJnqTZ0fl6pKvzkr1eqemdVqTuHHFyrcFZkRVb/hGOjMulCYJtllZFhPnxcY0my0uZr2QOFDT034nXL6JzUsVodi5psMX3NQs@6RsVaZHl5fGst26Kt5UjFvo1uVLKSIuF5l2RhefclmjXC/RFX08bERGSl9rx6Wsyl/WihGzOE5fzDu3yWJmLIi13lgdNztyZ2pKuRFdoJbZ8XWrJ8wL0mrO5SOl9jU9ytd5M54ehBv0SBR7Y7lqrAbnpdWgMe0N@snqOZMTnq76mXa0ntfYcsGIVJQl1W1mRGlVvxbZcS15Ubzt5dNSWYlma4JWO7@YLUKhriTW5tEVu7gZFSLSgo8wpWrmpuy7vgzVfSVfJlNTw9UBFcoVzjuD6JVPLQgruiRyT/GsT59OI4vcFL8suNRSZH0SlZlEoekbxg29kyyX5z2jeFPPdnh5lbgtj8ex2zp1Mysaqh5KXBbSSbo2ZvRzblQp3sYlpRCZZ87lfLLYWbUSZr40lRMXpUHusq7nmhP@JpkfNJbL8SBxKdRK4zQlJHL1@qg3aPcW3YZRWzLlCD/q@fLn@crTAPpxu1EIXbYyscG0Hm5f5ZRZrVnwrdSbTknLVsZsvpaYxprx8ISaLS4T6YapSFruvJyMXU@lUj6dG7SyrCoIN0/8FTvmGs0lkzDi@nXh5lozfGazp0Z6w0x4eV3u0u1bw4heSNTtohMrpsc6f9VfmJdGvKmE1Oo1w16LlZYcnXWkp25NHaUn9FXrZkX35qvCombyZmOsRvvx6Ph8YTzpqyv9ikp0R5zcqmTV0oiPXXWlVZyOskqzmxXLfPcyxKRbg4uyULiYDVYtYRIaXTxNL3iON2rpbu9cjs0Wmk8MJ2Ylqlnp3AziT09MT6h0k1J63KrXimaoydHTbqMUfSp1DaPAt4pSJiIp01ymez6eZG@XXNNYrKbNWE8WlzU9xOSpRaVbbvMjdWAUjFt@tLop3CrlaSh2Ux2JcbM/ZicSW2qLTLyi1X05X00@7w2WsfZUmPFgGWrXRY3NpEejKlVlJ/FZZpk0TOXcuKr0spdpKZ0uJULXWih@Mc6eXyz6UrvVrlz0OTVy28uGY9XegAn1M5X8oBaZDOK1SjxSylLN3vK6zvZzCYkdcnJ2dLmMaMlSKBOj2/P6xfWoOVQqcjbdWYiZMN9U5/EOJyotYRWL02XGNxomL5U0E6nFqJaZM1ulwjzsU66K5VBtueRvetw0zIlPXcPHd1fDVbUtcKo8LD3V2WZ7WspKo1E7luGbTDXTYKYrY85ppRqVzNUUNldazArzYaPDGFruQkv0FpV@tlYTelo/rIm9anohMrNO5/b6ulVVJjfXk4t6vFdd9blRtG2K9Vh1YVJPYPK0Z6VWobfIiYY4qs@elPPF9KZNR1rnk1KrP/ONkrfdWVi6qTKlSqYtctPi9SButioLrXwpizI9CVUHNDVv1VYrU0ir@cq83F2I7dUqLWWMJ3ZxRXOl82LuxvQl84V0rtpscLpcrZ6XcmluMi/PSzdxn7BqlPtRafx0S9UURQ7ptw05nmHCRqgVza2y/OicmZ5nJs3LZpLV2NZFu1y@YocyP@Hj3Wou1inznXT68mp5KXLtWk2rXbWaVNWn3NzeNulqUy4lxVKx3lSjxZle7nTi3FxNX3NMMTLpzUuLzLw8nXYmyUtf1xS4sLoSBLY@l0u0cAGyk6CE6ayWrdSMZehpNXoazHLqTTuZ1s5j6exS7M@E2YpJ52Y@2igs5v2YpCVCze7iXOzy5cHgqp4ZhrWZ1oxlo9RlUiwr7V52WE4uhauLUrswNYVGvxeRfAajjZrX6ZbR4pfSOR8bzlpGV4bOJ2rRZiabNOTbXOJKl3xMgs9QfKfM1ejSMHpTueyr8@yi3F7mYMqRYMUaE1WXSnuaGCsXV0bmqvN0lUgMWr2LMRQ8Hd4Oeanly/R7wrUoV6jbm6v2OF@btunR9U05Xmtd@BKrsH7@xKvDcy65bK6qDCOIycGsOF2EtRKfOE9cVXn5clGpt0RhEGuEruVzZUXllPiQSYvsfDZXaN8ymknkB2KmVVH0XIu/iAtqjaPpRefWrHZuElehc@aaaUzmTMgoz2lG7CrSslvpdkN9KjMzrrROg53lfRdmutsY1flzma506sWVuizlQ0YrXcmKV9P5UistJT18y5fOs3KNl1gwS6KxQVNvjVeZWY/qiItSNpOI34YuQIIMQ07OuxFO4A1tsBjRpfL0Ql6MpuO27pss6LrvtruIJoftoUHzpVKzUpzn9ah6aYwUKhbjQxcdXYsb9afJspg1c8N2S45kk@1Br3rRpctN8Sp5nW3cxoVojS4@CclOI8bwpWiHp9m6OpmZMCLxgzFVWjJ9nZcFnYtPq0/R/HTq6y9nU9On3cbPrxKdwTjLznjOF0731Cdu0b6UGakSFwZGtTOf3RQ6YCEq7VlLoQq3LS18JV2IjYt2tTxma@n6yqQzyQ5/Exl0dVZUxFk9bEYvi8Igzou5/O14lLsoPhWZrvjEzFlZv74OFy5YKi76Mqbal@n2tXatrEKckO5WE@V5f5WdDCuicFEM5fRuPdZvXHFyHoZR6anEaO3Ceem235OHtKgq1UadYajbWCjfuak/sbP@dW3VVBcX@uAyXZPDN2JRUWs3bTZ3rdOVeKZwnR3Vb7PLRKymyz2hOUg0lYnvPKzyXFopxai4MBMy7Q7dEqQwG1@setxYoNnbznicuKBXMWNFpxVjPkoMVsne@YTt3FbU8@ZyTJ9PFre1zA07FXwsW@M16tpc1aLn5x3f1fK8VRzIraLI09xkOTIuMlPhct67jqV9CY1p@vL99nBRqg20Tp6O93oJthEOdyLmU7@2NK4rVDtXugjHc0tzIebH08oicaGlY43lonUdiYxvR4tqohGrRxfsTB3nM1phEKXVGyOuLJoXg0JGyItl0SivevyEiq2mlWIhkfdFBa5b694yYp5@avRlczgQm1c34UaM5qMX1dr89jaXpidxcZQvyucwJs658mLZGHXHveuqEZYotdr1FWOr2Kpxe13pK7XOZXnYmw/i8Zp@0R4lp6uuVpfqPm3VKvbU81xtIudWNyBwsXoyOmrJ@VZHusnVmSplxjrpOdjgbKYkLQd0McpciQpzuZicJ28mndi4O25nZ/XuYjyKNeJRdSqs4mbnKToVWvHu5aRB873ufOgLnVNqY7W8yV9H9FJlrpXMmipcMYlQ6XbcmuSnLd8ke1XomdkOo/VCndJ86stGwSpIlNvJUKV3NcoUx@fXxsV1KEk1C9Jymhidx859NRhMpiOjmmjLIXlGd2i5PZ8J4wnDVXJcW1/0WoVSv9IPJWjNJ8Xn5lXs6bJbu@VMLaLQlLGM9eec7yIPFkRO6kYbvrapMROYizA3s/CVMgiHDOWm0eDNrBoft8JJIVLQ24raXqijdki6Po@P57x0NaIywqofkVv1Tr@yWM37yXGkzzVmrXThRumEs4o2XBg6G0tehdrcU22ih6umViu1@IxyPeE4ce5byJlcWW/MqP6gku53Ck9TcdaOVNOR9PKmz0Smt7MRq6xu8t3QqNZLD8V5vRNZ1efhTP@cVeoTSZvoIZpptpX8OLFoXQhX1OUqLyyHietMrR1pXY2S47A8GDdqzHJclUT@9taYssXuoHTN9ovRduY6Ob4QjbQQbyXFyxG9qPSqt7FsX4gwlG9YnNChbIkPX@ZvfOYlL0efpBVbMVdJUVlWWlKvMZiltVJ/1JpWMhd0hg3NzhfVSfiiToenXGaSyF3pXV2mhHw0vWhVyzFjeJs22xG1FpoltNuaNLgJ9WtDjp8wsQTo4HK/d7tspeuZealbuWgYaWWwEnz6/Eo5LxYKGYW6EDuVJ@OJU8VpOtKqlrrXT9dpfdCM9kyjyC6eBHq5VKqXWZ5fdtNFY1xpXzaUYpyZ9DPl@PWwX1Jaak0KX1F8Mj6@idNKg7@cMkKklo4Untrn/FNxFqurY8Xkm/lb1qzUQdkVo62q1p1PVtkhIy7CkfyNUR30tVvoraMVFZpe1Lv9ujhSFvP6pdm@Ck8a7Lg9l8cxhdN8kXyyWuXYQRhPwqI3qjJR5auBedOozK50mh6uYlNBOxeuJKoU0gbpYj12GeLOz7u5ZIudPJWEUKIcmabnoWq97FOigpYrDiYykx3XR8K1BFOGTqw2umQaFak1uJ1mb5LLBrXq9sSkctmZq1fZ8Tw3no2arUUYplfNdskwGvUbs1@chXqXcblXHfabuUL2ms9ynBGvKtl8daxN273J/CISpUaF8M2oHL@UBrFxvCgsu1dTLVm7XBWzw4uIr6tcJswuZ8pPVXn0VOmZZu8pLrUb15d0JxPnFeZpGTdvhh3aoC4Sk/x5RIivikM23lIms@m0X60ranFZuy4Dm@OhcPO8R6e1znXNbPcvBP7mogWW/qUqFBs3l1rj/OaiP@0rlBwG8c3S@tV5ySjc5Ma37LxYX/Yk1jeuXs2r0XhUTPZ8s@ikMpzmotFOfHJZmRVymh5blEHrD2rLWkmoV8oUOyl382PfpciyCb28as8i9bRwE@uV5@I8Es2lF8owkWgxi@vLc/460dOK80nrkh1c0/Pb5NiYcC2unuZVsUplnrTwMrcw80w0fxW7uLkWRrF5Pz8NFdPzRqcYM5MVsdOJPM3r87FQKbBiczGbh2qF6rWpRKKL9vXt@ApaIUrxg8V1Pi6UI0KfkVa3Wb2g9pQWl2boSzo0b7WvfepAeaoIvnEtVAhrsTyzqHEwM77NTC/7sV5rJHfOMxfJIdWP8Hlf04gVb2NPN09lSb8Z@eITUDkJsT67LoNJ0jNbzcjiWkx22VU7m@hwvcKKzV/R6cjFxTRZDIUuS8lSlzIa0QlIy9M8dHOZk0PXtXYzMvXlKrlFf9i4bdWz83LitstOap3G7BJPxsI0Mxero3prWSksWpIQy4/reTFD@YrXc6Oa1MR6rp3X6VpfLERG44vzwrkwveKni7ziYwbF1nL2NJ0IicuyzAm6UqibwzQf7ibG4QVf1NJPV21qecHlL9lsop3QxxJ/Oaq0jJEx62iilI48RRc@sz6qSVfRXL15o4xaw0pF57PlUNwQcuPGJHbbGi16MyHfv6REMznj5cV5JWYqmWVBummVry/7DWbJ1xKXlYK@YHp04anBzEy6lWjUmoNeRZdKIxg4fd2WqiZkUCnmUL2mOG1YZObt9FU/MTCy50yidLmotqSKj7nO10e5kDHTffRwUg3lVmr@MizO44P69dWE0bOz/tB3VYvTt6OMOq9QUbMf7nDGOFkX2W63TWv5@sowyolWz3d1LdNCPXQbz1ys2GYvrPWnw26iOzmfPXW75adeu3EBzXnjE2KN8hM1uL66MOJikmf7rUy2lFZnGnOpT@piZFJSu61QV/R1F7ni/Cl0xRRGxR5bqQxXqwx/qXeURG7SK2e55aiVaFPhfJXp34YF7bKVe@oWhtMRny0t@PCNemH4biKVxfRcT8RjbCQ544xwezJp@xJpWfLFw8PlMJTJz2I5uq/XO1S@6st2VBV6Qf02xlVoI9KvyKbRijcb@WQ9W8helK7yN2Ip2ShyNze@7nUxm083Y5dXw3HkqssaGTpTHo4aIWpUyo77tGkmplJDKhj5cz23GN6OryfT3jw@KxndlXLFTaXBhBU5bdwpKfFY@rr9FK0y4XyZzt@uZCUUjy6SVJ8X@5e0XB/fdBJS/oLuykOYQOdA/sc35anOi7oxTHag5uWVEs@2qoO2fiEPa0Ch3JtqvDhJSuOhEL6l6nQjUYh35CuRr3brk3i3J900L8NxcbqA@Ws3t7oSczS0eqvbGE6Zm1geTNdI5KnYGU6uZ5W2UY/m2s1SLUK1n@o5kS3mS6X2rdlnK1VmUJiZrXjiIs/yk8y4kl9mepnivMC3Ohe@kS/U7POzQjst59t9zlgsb5kko6fFERUbxcoZMcea82hb1CPZy2E1zMlFdVG9TGiTeu0ylLnMX4vqWGcy12nnE2svkxMpuhyI6fR5u9jNDqj0dTY3CrVFg68rvnmRgGUKMve7n31UiKDrCgGjZqrUR@T15/YxFyfvHDxBTp7Aj7fvnDuBnX22DxIQ7eergRYox@9q4SeEj61CyN5mEL@lAG8tnrzcWwywznEC5ILP8UBH5M0E4s5GqEvHmddkfJSU9wggO55kBwXvg5HHk39hHMMXaPA7KIFN5Ik6D@GN96u0EY7gcz7wGZrMw8nWlqeH3aYGEwhNxiki8NPv@gU@VeE7yEi2gPPVgnfftj5zspMfiDM0hZw04goEXSSrfSoGxrSLwmpNHL8@m4EiB7I4G2vvvHeJo9kEE0uS8z2Q4jf9k7vkg/@IT7mQYEqcMjGm@rw/HqjDmYhkpI16C365ekIoGkFhKCv0nXXEJhtL0eTE2jj8JlCSsY@Hsk64JOcV4UOyyBmI@EBNN0KB9RFTH5GXBPz459h18kpK0dHEkULrkI/JXewhpaSYk8md8nCi@Hxe05cyfazPgyO@Y70n2tT2RLwzH8hT@/QRKjuP1uO3EmDfX1VENVXhh6rbQOTdw9vPnJDDwJwONOG07f40E3hT1bdjRCxP3GSnI76OwrvE3IuckurAmUtNwFt361MJZPzWdvzzYRqLnLxOxzX88AEfoXFi@05sV@ALpU17ssQfUx8IP/EWOH6c/vjYPhSGR1huP3wgcZIVadGCJMODk0@cVF7VlnZmyQJ5dOpyuoXyzIP3Vr3@b4F0oHogk4/4HVI6gFkgFnt3wBGgJlujXosqHC4JynofFJ/j4z3Bp5ygj06ac@IPhsdyQ87deTSRRE7pgcspskHJGRjIa584QWLvJPzQG3ElOHNbSR9G04lG9p@DFr02R/BrLx81TtLXOYPGFL8k2YNYzAzJIRq3AA484/PYZpwpbDeN0xbY8Y08fIXrg/HVyFtOgGCe0/Ul1o344QOMr6@SPB@s96p6kKlajpUWGXZeUg2v3dTAOHyetFtzHyPiB3cCUWRL9GQrdQSpuK5vJE8gecKZwzeShxj31HgrWYdk/LbVN5IlSLaeidyfrkK6tdP/BoCJvTxBXB9N9dHkJNljHeiBjwJ5thS2B/l8DmPXIoCshrHaYzc/so9GQR@t1rGEbUe8oH8SsbIAsEh77M6D7zfSQlLxcdseSy62yrR4gr6grxZmO0cCix9JSaB2cfneox38aIsA6H@gStHrdKdwq7XXFd2RnyAMOwPc2sCsMPrxx/coswVxV/7YB0f6rBbCfrhbNbS4tcFjvQxy065WppWdaX8e@@iYbe3m@Ehs6uF0ytBGhVh9a9OvRUnpQxmA@ON2NHZ58qJPm5g74wEdr7XHho9Wt/g6H0OvpAd7RJEe6Ue9TZD/dq5yWO4hJwcjcm@jLPA5YdzJK3Yaa@jALvQZQK@5@ULO@B2ZsXvpz63st9XmAOgjnZrw5sRStDyYhmc2gXvI46x23dYJFrJD97EVj19yKe0ik95AZp2n9wgIzFOgAY9sjhp3xkRJCVrPpIKeZ0IRP3Ext0CeN2xylNW38OmfoHNhxtlD9hS/92tXJaE9rHkFvq435tfZyy73onqWpt9fuTvroWb3JzemEb2WJyJ1n2CUPEYMWh/cdIKev66H/mGc@bJpvh17x/C8rSucRnck8VtE8PkNRn9VyHarEHpAOxzHJBDN8JUhiRxCuH9Q2rjWPzoxjtul1bfftMAwVSe76ZhmC6GTAIbydi6/bXOdbVSnffrio@kYN/6NFYZft2lJBZjsJ9S2OsfTuQIZvLdj10dHEY5sp@An2bGFqTuUSaJj24IZ7OQL8o@4mS0mY35Cnx6oat/jGEy2wUAwOCd0AJDfOs5qbVZZ5uWmeCjONnrRwD7lwxl3TyDmox1FxhWIwManLZuYiKMB6TYnuNts2TeSQd4GS9LxaARFOU8fYGdFS/ug45fxGHptAn3Ym8nR@PhMMnJypa3nyUi8ox5cWe7/L@56u9Pocf3rzqdwyW0LLRBI@@w@N/@eEkIS7klCFkjbnDTbEpgkswWGw0AI92k/@65@ku3xDJBk732xp6dhZmxLsizLssYjDXEwFMMhW@vtDJ7bgUCdXdpox/EteQx@LfEySAxPHd3yT3frEmwFRdjEdtDNKcjclqVmezsDNFbgf/1z7eX6NBqvXwfDdX94T0b19dxbU/5QkqBtqunkpvA7Dgoj0b3WJnwumw8hkpjQSAFbcejPsqhDljOiiGZynsSk40OLZQ9xgPnceN@/75HVLxFbRmH0wH/ntFkoFaejScglGhHHrlM/g59xPNUSf0WkdwyanG2GE9fJ4vsCeTqXs5KFshhIZQQ5zjkgLtGSFW7mayaD8QOh@jzp5ZUXFf1O9w5EQPZ@ynaKhosl@ZcXmaFHrDWwAh@v0GVfokyM@OwoULB1Es35nrqP@zIu5AkfcYXc632KxweCUdIPwxGEHEdB0X6bGCCMf9Fq79eazaJOLyMn1nHKXc4x4xNBDljH6RHsMV6cVke4QBmUF@gsYAu@nRg461/mEdBqNmEqzMBO4RXiEUoPCmW@W@iGrZ@T6swS/txJ30XgZUlH9RiRHQXexc2yTrOCaWYqO6x48SQ3Ot0uAkGc@IOQKK76/T4RLbx4EbMDl@CIwf/O4o8ugfPKEi/lhYXyQqK8KOVCVFyr2L0bx5U23UqZtT/jer9UJq6WX8C1o6jT9VOOLlUMxw7dW4/VjYq0SQviyrt2KEUqbcF2oqDglPx9yehLyctEGyvgtvxSyrV8b@iRt1Qm6n5M4sevpwfI5xgM@pPFlJQWh0H/D3E/2hLWsAphlaQ5xpvFTialdohodVIgNUFCzNN2dyeG8q5sNA7Pmczu9sdMUbuk/simyZC8aAsTa8kccbjEON8x4x54JSE8XPzSAcEwIWjKzNxd03iuG88dsKj10qD1TKTQ5ASnrqWn@A6Odf/EHzPZk8SZemvLC18I5Q/SefnSIskgVrovM8vZlNQmk/HUl4e6U4@sIjHueRriciVxGmIH2r2DprA4ffke5CacDnsvrZ5wFYXRFAt8tyWa03GFshHfVUOIwl/eP9ffeoedAVmFff9BVWBTdzgkvpf42GbiR5OI5oBPHRyraDoa9QMd103N@HMO6Wd54zd8jBBDdIyGolfHB6JSP48r/XEMNSqqBiDP8J1hXBBNb5EMGp5g5DUm1XoTEMhJ0asM5xyZmMOgbcgnL76aIo4rFHCftn0OETJyMnvY8wArreiZD4ukqzcyv4cTMoGo4yHHPESo1U3P@9s06P6oHqqNUumv5dL7ssMy46ouFd9/UHXHRDIFG6VyqfRb@YPnVcPRXD5tzHZzgPWhAIB5dYyF/hPJpn@PvMNehVYMrhiR6R/543u/V/S8pt9jH/D1lDkCUZ5GvkRR5jiveEK2FeLdk7k7iPKKtl13UC/4xfossWu7HFgj7@EbopE/HgQT@dIovA96YKD5buom7PfDGTui8cmS8AONBv6EmPI2p5IkcVxaTQvbLhwulriB5AocwO86vOc40poNZKcGCL/PHwB5CKIICC4yya3uUEL4uv1OMIA4LSEAUZZiDhgCqGu9add/lAaPifg3aVC6Y72wO0Vk3o4ZmXXSfiHPFZru/jgg7RszmEeFmzm00wC3j@ot1WoctD9XmjVF12fNxqf6fm1f7V2o9lFNVRtnF5xCSx01jkm7tFTldJ@enrab9b3zdoMeZCotapnhAq9yeqFqX86atVZLNZqqfnJ2XCdoBL5ZOW3Xa628qp9Wj89psT7MK4KgThttdVw/qbepWruRZ6ymmRe3U40DdVJrVo/otrJXP663LxjjQb19CmQHhK2izirNdr16flxpqrPz5lmjVVPomLdfb1WPK/WT2n6R8BNOVftUO22r1lHl@DjV0cbn01oTxCd6uVcjKit7xzXGxP3crzdr1TY6FF9ViXlE4HFetc5q1Toual9q1J1K8yKvgbZqfzunSlSo9isnlUPqnJd9gis0LtXzZu0ERBMnWud7rXa9fd6uqcNGY5953ao1P9WrtdaW8o4bLWbYeauWV8iJyagJBnGLyul677xVZ77VT9u0ZpyfteuN0xwN8mdiDFFZoab7zODGqfSWmNRoXgAq@MADkFefj2r0vAmeMrcq4EKLuFZtu9UIITGx7XZTndYOj@uHtdNqDcUNgPlcb9VyNGD1FioQTOD9XCGk59xrjBPRJZckrJ6R3DwPp6ofqMr@pzoo17VJAlp1LS3MtuqR5jnN5XVv6Su3R1/gLb7l066Qx4PEVxv7NbL4JDlLJn5@TovO78mXd4kyWmhsId3qt6C8Vn3r@dfT22/B8CbE1tw2kzfYg@g2jxRFOWQk/eo9kmtZvyjnBmtr3759qnyjfW7r27dc/jktE2Q81UJHYX2sVk73sR92erzNT/iWXEbtvtax3vMSeNn1tby2zoecWl/v@boZPl4EYOMm0kkJCFgPmpG/auwMlYOSXzEnfUWcMSPtLDKvN8OI/gx/xjeyNjgPSDnLuYX1dexhmQxkPlGWfkLCSUF0ZhA@BxDcMMpi5Ps/brMlFx22/NpBlTNtuO6EtoG32dwTza/921TzQro9E4tvTdlYMeHgTZh2CGbId5plSo9Lccw9y4prj39yhhpGREZhTlDxh6z69En2tTRHfFHxFea2bChxTgdyUvlS/4zNXGnjw1bq@ZF9LnMLX50jtw2td5fc7op/jq6kAk2wANsvYkkwl1eq6@tOG7LK2J60lRGr/g6VZkGP1lQs1Xc@L@uIkC/hgt32tBiPgweXelLDh83Kyd75wQFpTlD74fff/vqXLU9H3B9PvuTl9wJ4kHWSuUtW9CwgM42LnFlSJbvnYCFZjpPdB6OHisj4aAaNH3bIpLWRM8VGkPwa4gZCdyNkGBgiyUYGSQLGGYXv8/2XnpHXpTNTC0A20dUcejPoPLCF3yFTiWWgK1Ey@3MetQf8AWw7/c0Utx3SAqRFzB@MJnOSXNpcsN7LHJiAA7y34c@KUaWYMXI86pgzSMIY6EyOwoBv8PlOy7YzimTXYqAxX3nYuSUR8TJNhUnSwimXCMVZGJkZLA8DevJFyxtdXujkQChCqofKpEVsPLAtCyZ5j/ic9cTQkK92d2iIXr@2mLYVHKk5TZT4/5OpY9zZwKTIgQaVAmxOHlk@2xJ2Qn98k1N/iqQiqjfgbGmJ1fckucu6o6FsmZDo@t5kkFECK04ow49mFodnqlyYKpadCTb9v/jB8P@DPFkCf5s2nAQ95hbr4WA49Z/JSYYqvKLdKzMlmJkTY84xtZib7qOLGMwvd2DubMf0MbwHebFELNCjMzcPLiSlWHYJAyDk8Gu48xcBfHkS33Vo5/SR5@4LedM/HnYHo6xJyGWWigW4V3m2ufLmiBxucvIKv6QcdMfIr/KR4zyyzsCGi7TY9Vy9ijIC412ZdQ46vf6WnR52lrNogg1lM8NjcSrpqWUm/4M@YRSvMj1T@otM0dXJvuzrEOQUSih88wbEKBA@@@R2WLONcO6C0KX9RqQX9vIrvYojYySpQF6XVZvDc0SdG94zYynSsTQQtAMoAedVT@dsuvYnMywXfYHOMURiaCr7isOYAIn2RVozwijfXJG4zovszFLPbkrIq6X@fPhjiGTHvri4TI1iIgOUG4K1qE46nAyq/7x@Z2Lk78DW3ST@@pDjqnTlfSVcc7xzJyzY6b@KYo6QxTmDdUnrUMylTvcHHmaMjAazQvBAP4yroHtuchrRnoEz1i0z@n@t3BBAVlJnYFXm69A6kTZlIdt5ZcwXXMnctVcXuNJ@5h3qFBFHT3BgVptBIBl2Ew5pLs42pi8RVgeHTzfJcprNited6aAzvOkMgv6cT53@I7wbrkfDaTQqjuZeJpNJegMRCBwhUoj2ia8@B8NeOIvUHk0HOJJap@ets6Tjz/F8VcXzpdT/EA61x5i9BfA3iJkUhTcTGhp/S8119u9x7O5hP6H2tLBba44HCEw1ZgEivANrGR@enqtDf@iPyR484zOX6jjo@kNSH2RM8SnM6E40DaofAHtLY1cHsF3Ys7Ol/ICdOta352kEGloeopWlqUgEj3VaRfjm5yTqjk@wuNjhuF8941S6C0c6GhCcpjA2xcV5M@3nPeRu/FxvH2EzLhtz9s3QsmZ8ffAliuk0EGctdWbcGU7mxBQv7bwhsp/y3RQVBwMiiN5qdvKmboBk6T24/foRdRWp27UW4BWEpqof3CNZHLvhnjNGfM5Wu81ivm3p@Ip5SV9nVEdi9Lx49PLIGVrMq9/@W7V9yK4663e6tMNSrSmav39PduBeGE1Q9aSiVGmjXC4Xyu/hoj1vVYo8EfDfZBDzvPrJWaPZJkbqEPlGMOyaCeZz0i45jUXsKCB1F/X@OxSyqU8ac@M7Mw8muInjm9mSNxaZzQyNfbcDdy/1MEqaw@yShUs@HHPiMESDIhFKTEfCiqAHSNHHShKYHOh5Tl2mk4/J0mLp5Gh@3OA7aOuTXPXxPvQ7N@ZnpAD8B35Grca8M@jpsPc0JgN/YKkPJmZ170gFL53zzDJMfKkkHG/yb2AlEfdyLpyejzMSEbIHDKL77ph0S@eeRA5HWExILJIZ1k0525vOddAPaA4QXd27EAuOqCszEOyCcDOieTziNtcOFiSmZUm2AppdvXBgqwpVnmeDwenno2jeDdXaLW2zsdOKRr7f40wJ05GkAkB5kWZ5n1YOCRO3GecI8NZKfG5yTMoGKVlI9037iB2LWH/XMuae6Q1JlQkv2L7Dtl4AUY9aE56kyNiWXbLDziu8583xsHdIINA2B0asCPRHIEZ5vJQiqmi8WSD4isUlj3BUfR7vdBxANORkRNEoWQBY8lbXTxYY8Oi7vlyoIEK6YwlIhRg0xEicLLlO@MCSN@gvzp0iaFpW@kidm@csMw8CpNAU30CobkP8ReWi4Zi8I/T5HeFC4MIHhOQleOma5cWaVMsmEHFqbiyBWVgK8/1ymAUNU7@srA/vOWAbWrFYSC8kGnRI@hGMiLt/GBrVy2Hl@qG8YLK9v@2H18jbRJqCsOFnno8H1n3MO7AEo91SCSKYzDe1bbqkSdffNhnbRW3T/PB31bbxWOx@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@SUKODnkhrh8qleeE8pc9zC9jHiJlTMhJFnnDmna1StJZCeAcl6iFfi/asBx3NGd2CvrlaWeHvZVEmFhmXF/TCxsZTPuj4mFVHaG/XGxMLkMLWu5fVouEiMhLMChRL1jYJ@Sq4NMwYNb6yFViwmaX7mxzP1@dgm1jlbVvk5vwVSyLNKpS5I4@OdBBmZNBxpNiCMx79KOxlXcW1rjuj/8no3IrHtvt0i7meSSIKOZTkSAThsMPEZXOaTMtg1IY4sTTO@ZB3J2kyPav5ENC@9BkbXr9i75dW8CrFlVSrlFg9JE74@J315KfGExi0K8xdpczA9vT5dpqnHgKRz3UDvjLXnj6z1B1TuHqmTvnBFKsngFpMKzIBWeAWndgaQn9ntaL/lybYw8df5TIL5@XYTBP3@njZSGQZq2F8CJjX3wrDN/CuZLMrbW@ExdR06V2QaxnfwUjD/SMDgv6J19G6cf3nXgdftffxyms3Ks5GxSVpZQZKlaWyQrD7JYa/N@V9czphLvbYs/ru8CuxNYe3qkJY6xboyjxHf2JdBaMqq@BRbP//IK/uWdYU3OByE84YYha9n7N6dDEYwQD5N8KmYbOIosuQ/VBUlGPF6aVn68W01HP0bC05XNck/25KM4fBynU5m6JhorIXFmCxcrJ7NaGf22bHv2JP61pfhH4YhsnJulBHD9Afz44pRKqfTYNE1trZ@1li1dzxb75dptqdwkz5/krxe6vkFdx4fpNKmH/kyv/o9B1n0xI/B/sOQvjYysIPLVUiLxor2jnVtqOB1c@2PvOVNdWhTxI3uk1ZLreWtrqtKlLbOOjA@vWJfT9/kaJcxgCEKkpiO8r4nkcCcmN3xkvghwum4vnA25djEDFOyjHfidoQ6VrxfM2zHeX9i6eaTvxMddjCEYdonRke@4P79LTuqer0twIvkRtm4tH3tINXBqKvIxJk2W2JrZeXJPK09XGDjWquFam2lDxcgOXoa@Fctc20tkmOeWu8CeYz09ZhCREK9CqTe8KdCPy@jmamZOR5aVdmiewcpl5pb1cj/D3Jo/19z6D3AyPaCec62tB73Abj6p1NKbfO9f)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))
- Gaot++ (140) [local](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)

### Explanation

Gaot++ is a fairly simple stack based language. Commands that match the regex ba{2,} push the integerthat is one less than the numbers of `a`s onto the stack.
Commands that match ble{2,}t do something based on the number of `e`.

The only complication while writing this program was that the subtraction command takes its arguments in opposite order than what esolangs seems to imply.

```
baa                                                  push 1 [1]
baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  push 49 [1,49]
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet                                     duplicate [1,49,49]
bleeeeeeeeeeeeet                                     duplicate [1,49,49,49]
bleeeeeeeeeet                                        print [1,49,49]
baaaa                                                push 3 [1,49,49,3]
bleet                                                add [1,49,52]
bleeeeeeeeeet                                        print [1,49]
bleeet                                               subtract [48]
bleeeeeeeeeet                                        print
```

This code has been separated with spaces and placed on the end of the line with Cood and stones.

Comment: What complication? *Whistles innocently*

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen It took me way longer than I want to admit to work out that the subtraction was doing Top - Second rather than Second - Top.

Comment: *Scratches whistles innocently off the list of terms that reliably tell you're joking over the Internet*

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen nah, I knew what *whistles innocently* means, but I somehow managed to read it seriously and as a joke as if they were 2 seperate comments.

Answer (score 6):

## 141. [Floater](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Floater), <s>6171</s> 6055 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzLz
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11xx4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>+.--._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWW/wwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1 "
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002160 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6184 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille,
**139** in Core SNUSP,
**140** in Gaot++,
**141** in Floater

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZsWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQokiap5z6@yGAG6STdmOlJp4N00p17b6YHE2D6Q9CDAbrRAQaY/tq/4nwNBnP/wZ1VRVIPW/beJ4lsicWqVatWrVq1alXVYrHHGcPf/e4Af1BNlZcDWTWRKRgm6uvSTNCDKLNEnznJiIbCFIWh0vpgOhEU0zimDhCLkKTwUh/ukamOBUVaCTrEhxDSdHWgcxNkDjkTCQbPaYKB1KmpTU2kivuzhRHKT9SRFMA5J5IyADBT0DVdMEl6BKGWInOTXp97kRJ9UaCmQ7qBcoL84@RHE/HqZMIpfQMgYwjlqpl8Of0CQxyhK1U3BIyHFwxDxZEJhBZ5gX8BmgRQTpfUcrpy/iKJZdA5kM5psrBAXM8wdY43JVXBSSxqVFqN2k4OwtKarvanPK6uORQgGbNIlGTBoHioyhnS7IYJ4gA6QLrA9S0wSlR1hLOgyVhGEuI1DfVkbhjkkSwBbIFJIAFzFK0gXR4aaKFNAIOhToRtOgykCEIfGZrAS6LEk9KRsDAFxQDijSCS@DGaS7KM@oIMGTYk8X5AhqbGVpRFQJDqqxSCD6@9qMD67lAAGEVwmCBowFTMBBW3AXDE4cVc5zQNiAQmNoBwU5qAKEmm20ACZ0hYWCGLISh9wj9tLcYq4pTtWqKZxCEO6J3qBLch6LhtggQvGgq6ACi5tSB55rpkAgswe9OoJnA6auqC4N0V6Z0ioTAVl2DiigRJ852euvPVghua0coR5DSTOtDDzesLikPBFDp8PIFvyuU6ofKVHPpyeI/DlgRDU2u6h/Oi1C@RQd/fC/BdsD16oD9TgJUCrsiIVjWT5gIaEBgwgUCaw0EcCsxCQU3eKhidvmiLLeGyoPrQGqikoLaf1Iyf6jrupRumcmOotKwqA@AnVFafKpgfCoox0AS8Cp3Mj4QZcE1VrDZS54TDzaEEjWbgJtnqF5auIQwFbQOyZ3PUKddQ5SmBg5yGiQUQuAJZMcaSiNpI5CQZZ4F0jMqiWheMqWziPFOlj1sedInQDyKHDF7tY6CJOoPiOEBKIqAvTbZ6ICEKgKEhVFJVnPTTv/zL/mAAeNI8r@p9W1zbqK/yRCtyhFhQNQgLrKpwMiEL4Py4dCs7FDDjZKnPmbh4ZWkXQYggpc7VqdxHKhSozyXoWkNuBt1RFAXeFCwhtxSpH024saU3JEtyoeITrgcNSwogZZNqB9DnLLQSL1AHRGYCk6kpJlBAyyO3QX/v@XTs@fTxXgDivEHv0SFND05A4IJHJAru3O9JTju9o@gMkzNUqU9pS3OoKiEU4JGLT6maoHjcOzjcfrfec3uDWJ95vCdSig@KktL3uEHGM1Cu23vCp/g76fjh5EXu7RIByxxjwb1V8PBeFwUah/SJGT3hJCWoLVE7YIe20lTjEXMcJwe3ojFfXsbNrIgDMo5gsVSxfIAaChqyIGgeJsh6sZbAcHurjRP2VfQFDrvCx9KDz33g9m1XnWCAmu5UFPfVpqRirSVrwynoaGCKYmigvXUsujwHwmNgJW7CYO5HPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dQH1QI86YkR6pNXjcP4A1pM2hk0PcuB2O7TQ3@rPoAugS5vGK6Usq3MomNCGhy/QIAounBtAE0Fmq0Jpq0JWiSRmt2pjBfQKxtYTUCLQk6Av4F4Hqt0W/a06Ang4ZMEANquvbKmgCbcELLw1JG76DZJE6FIT0BL6EvECVj2ggwRrXMGFTEk3NMCMwQYNEwhFo7td7VVPM3U6HbgFXb2i3@1QuPLbfQrrGyQKcyRzymDKDbAlpUAWjucFzbT1FdTEMEEjvRx2SGTAHkODxpA6/PyybDKW2KPrVhlY11utZ4@IHFYyti0VkEGnIs62BlFf0kE7ycuXpQPA7EXhrh8wyA4BP7jeIMExBEDIhIXAT01QbiDI86HED0F2MXWKpR6tsehl8RC1XToo@IC4LhoTw559F6KC9DoKk/EmigBu0dd4YIzFqM52Ikjjb0e8j5kzJnsQq2sSYTzYig3SXBBk7ys4J6qi7kEKjFyjxSC7KVY7gEHWwMYgjF@O9UU669pCXDcRtBloD@j5IH9D09SMYxguJHM47QVBUuimviyZVQULC23qS8lUrXBPVnugng3on7RTAs1Pe9LiRYVI3LoNRwY1AztMNFAKBvCnKUidxy0aoDhJfBYDbyW5iAInKKxfFwASoCAwyiMaRCUXQKk0lgrvcQVJVwpCp3P5kQt3XJcXAjjXmi9ZdYK1EOoQ@wAbfBkdNJcI2srW/UT1c3tHvPUYQMw7tzs4UiXF88X98eNH97H7DDT8x4@fIHSKQ59wyAehTyQUICEMF8QhksNPQjj1juTAcQ/u5zsH88L7gJttgUenlaR5uLvj4/CDn7tj7WsIX72g6kCzAXQAXwCP25tK4aDX6zqbQ0WDPdGqfd3ibJ9IQ11QBpSw0FTdRJVqLv9YSzeLKRc9NXRalnq0AuPr4wR6MMxlXHvyw6TEyQ7BuqqaKdJgOJ5AFwDInsNRpjqFPg/zD2kimSUy@5EVLNibRnNSs1DuBkFNEkzKHo02so4nQpu2gXoQ@NL2nEjU1clawxmUwA9V5DoMu7AtvzNNxcO@nRrBqVN7kroVH8fxEzzBDPLUgOdRQLVu15E2YAID4klnECZz1MDnw5BkErqOtCGTBCWeiAb1nhP5hWWecfx6Fro1jmxj3Jf@dqY1cpYgN5SpoeHKEZ7tmU7b8DEM3Fd7gryIRQKCLAbNxSqI1UUsQlkXFOi/BbEnL7VY7ctAmdD3AwvxRQKnUxaFTRjDyjBlQWXJIKsP281MrTvIPeWyOnB4d3RybVJCG1Nyv/3r2sZChBkEZKxidbkJPYKxF91BAdP31zlFyRiSnx3QVxS9TiG5jUlPJD97AI5tmwq6BJ7gY5Zc4OkhNutUFSnCnICR0YEgA1ZJCkfXyQWPE/vo2R3xdojpCeIUpox0T1Jw@CtggWSCQIq9nvQWKPAFk@5c94Dp094@toFwDV8ZRWiH8eZUN2Whb1//2@/3oQFeN8@QW8JUhx@vA4/AN9xUAfHN1rKz4hvys79lCcxoKkscYQMJfQ0lz@HpKCevA/tRY5WMAoEhp0PjLp3GBeHEPzC8viNnFuW6IE/7gnPdXwhh8a7pZeVWpAmpEVyxHUnG0TeyvzAcrfx4Oq/LKtcnWKxlFknYtLbVLsKCG0Dl6C2NBBryG@h07Du0WVcBQ8acWr94KeVr7Spp@LufK8e7QsZEuR4rwDSU60lv8BGTEXtLsq0Og02PgChzYyv4iIP7K2tVR5cGAzC57OtbYGBfwxRI43iBnpPLO2LhDAaIDPTcezh12fp9C8RZFF4H3gKEqsrk5@cIHxEHHnoIlh28oBnYYpP0grEy11tiE23486UIF0hGWVAyKd7nY8J4wF3PgDdLp5r2dn5sIZD8yeT@3NYqK0HAq6IoCF/ruTD6SBNODoT6W8E3FbFj0m5Ce0BH3IwDY1fmDBAS02azMINmIT/vCS4eUHgsLpvQO2K7IcdZ6HhrrrzJo0m8KkuGRprbuXlLI76cZWzQ4HV08rPJiu9e87cPhj0erAPr0P5OrfImnq@@IUffoKSsqSKejG8JRlB9i3e8OsffN82EoToTrN/9A9dqL1XfoIICMpEMmCy@zt7nvyaueOGT/Ozn4ngvVSYv740/Rleqqg8FxUChIIPNHIWs1sOwLcvW3LVZqr4t04YkqwZqkN/3eAETAsOwfvdL8zbbJE4J8EOrj63D@7PtJYoMcihNft9oXE4eqHIsMaA5@HlTAqa6iDW9ff1WDbfWUCz7VQ21NnpUhbWvb6r2Mfx/TTjIOqyOlye2gu/YUvvUmT2tfbuCMC/Aa477K1dgEiRnkLZmcW81gM4P59zSuf4DRo@3uOuMHtqSmMxg0@EMyQQETN0yo/8hpUXeL63/bTrqFdr41yqx1bhjWQCNTX5fNSkKMezPzMEyzLdrLFGeClNhrwap9kYCiM17uuPbiWLsahza6x40MA9v0a6hVvaE8JuoxuM5vntX4XCyBJ38q9bMXlWjgZ2t4Ql0DQI1HHidcaBMtZ3G3eJdfarU3@fcUHN6ttrfIRKn/FyNlPi6zbRjihsC@b5ltucnKkx71QnYEMo3tL@NlCwRWb87iEnMBvNIwqtV@rt4j9F6HRPsV7BHoFWlsRHAS17fpnhCb83XCXAyCTMyRTCX@Pctbu9TpD1VlX9O64A@7UvYTAPjE/sqfK2VXtk@9pI22qxMGHiVoye@tSZhjTX25BG4hyfKbzZ0DapkksHhW1r51RrgO6PW1org1@aQMGKThR9D553wW/TWcedmg4lg/F2CnVUx2gm8hywZDH@LfaQ5Ri9ZcMWLtNay7MbZ4uCF/tGWwCmpHzD4oTARyO07Fj/XH00N5/Im0ELF3z3JQZosmb6RT5Ogwyv4d2cJeMskMlVFMGiT0wcCnqvIAgfWqBX7lpJ1VmL3Mrc04QZC4auStVl2wJudvC7tBPcvQBxb@w88ZPuKGrGmgaoyFpaGc91vLC95aM/p5F1s@zo5j1c3v9qrg/Te1eev2HzKUB0qQ2Gok56xvnurb4BEmpYb1nuVAPqHnDHGu7u2QtLMMgo8oa3Z3tDY5rOsyvK38BmrRktRqur@Jdg89q/qQ9afhXfJ9SDBvnx1tQ5GcMIuMpS/1YuGwhQGKkM1VU0IkLu3QGW81mP97l9VLlXdBupIgt7HNcFSOYGipZ4soLkEJIyM7X2C/etIPVnlsCvBO7Y8cMa5fsvKFK/q@226c041wUx9f@wtEHrebRp7b4v4Qq23yw2/7cQFcZJuu@wYa7@4g5LC6wLZPHc2U9EB3tKfTqYyZ6p6EBE4j4fz@bxeysqEJ9QDBcAcKOKZhN0VLKcnA8mSYRJYSUR3d@jwy@KYOWafUQq5jl3o4cHCSjbO8wuNuBTVrax3h9xD6tAdCLgP3ffKMWLcBFSQYX6zF5TbgRMlcrHo3FQdKdyEeEjgsFPTE8sNwxgST6chp/ShJVswQJPFGFW3nAksj5UmXoX/r3/Ttx3AQCMbaCIZYM8OFOy0qE6EoTr/ZJVrl57WNA47kGEc8yFeZsalB7JpZIAcwghE/L7UOWoVmgnbjcR2q4SbGtbDW1RYjYptA@zcZFqNZlHTVwVLLOyC17mcSvGqPJ0oIP19c2gEUQP6hEDcVNYbixDCYIqpYxXQ96MS6gt4/bOPCSPjn6yqY7Jjiin5r39jOc9AooRFCIed4onv3FaJCI/pxGOF59UpUO0gWQm6aoN4MJNBB0@xaQlCLVjxXsQPOeLVA5IYcHxacDGWX0s23UCBPHJj30@8U34iiZ7DdP28fcc8pH6JJrTw336f9n6x@eb6RSDOGi4/ckBOnrFcbSczkLxJdSPX4cJlVwt7GRKnurVQ2Z7EHhwmzeX4qEyIgyKRO2FOfFTI1q@Chxjs@acY0D/g1ktQW50mdeiZWnZMoGGiKHaQBdOAg5Dl0kh8vbC/Bc5yuEA/oiGWlQCP2CgDdxZDZOziM0llnD2s8PY2I50TelOy5D4LBUPhFKnO4WPq9IyEdKGvYo@7u@/vFyEmcL@I5x9ow2HO/f3iF0zoBringmI9/I7GHShfyX05DJ4xP/5ocEvkcj27T6xtV@jlh19qpVq@0Uw3Ww3g5rNV2YOCqk@4jabAsqDJHA/dRyaujMAWXRKMr2uPtQZZ3wG4x4MOOXSKfaC93nXCGtRmtSvgOrSCaxCwNbZzfyX7vvyGsJX@GsDWTKKEbC2KakSQbJlxG9sa1O/IFm4X3N2noLMdjuBN8D2qkPDIhVLApQBw6Rt5hF7X0mrBTyQCmvHrjHofxz4UwKsNxGsAzKR1Wbi@VrpVub2Vf/4nqLEG49o/tsYEx7s1xhDv1RgAN9lIjkK6VG7V87uZQJw2futgxen4aQSR9C3LA9aSLtX2tnQ0EzGADNuraq1bDTSTDGIgYXkT8cgAsw3SHcnOm4G1C8KKLIjSsgGavN8H1dRbmlizgUoPEm8Ly@UioCDXATAruB5o/chFYVgj9drrDjTXHCbl/A9W5kMCRzAb1B4v4XuB/ulf/qXlGXxvQviP7LAI4X9hhb@nMYNeezdaNK5Zg9nSLtWQQSwzXPEJt9iqEx6x8IgoKVMBSRPg4IwwBINbxG7qu8HjuWsDP6ERgJlY9WJtS8oT9AcP9k07pmlsYOBZdZDs2AsLaAdQ1sRV7WmKPbVhgKBj0ViEpYHIwMxBGJAshAHNQuj1HoOsUTNJS/3Q49Hp6SlyGTwnC6nYicVI@pD7Puz6YU3oIcBSli1yhyAPZNnkgLQzO5vnkPOxXpwVdzk360YPJ2BmWO0CI5WHBADEi6MVmx8uGApVm1XQ6IqwMIk6Xzo2Fhg4CnE5Eix/fQdRABBZuLFD8UvZ3WwEYweZLWkObjeDq4PBGhjs2LVPdO6@R/fmvfJg@5UjEJhf7xEkBcJ/vMfZfC096dduzp6XTsq4NuhzQ1Gxc0ABqEWeEB0K02zMu9VTXDYqoBf3ix8BJfQE6Fm8II1UzUhn86WLaq3xyk2XQLpfgrmR@@zUdx8I@u8e1gH3C6l3mJop0I2rTMFh5TZVm/U1DLFZZHtJ5r7SXlL6Rukdawf@ddkk4VVBLPOtiMk0NlAg69CvsW9S6S3ArLVD@KpUj/fL893D6dm9cvCq@B/3PcFwEDzCwgWhe4M8v@BGe3ROyfEraOKnzoyg46gWcm2ez1m751n3m@i3HW3Xz7BtvG0dDwbsaRs6o/vCjFamskwF3/BtgLoHaaso4mpqEebQC7rGIZXFpG4K5KlXa6Tb1CC7Lq8ft7M9DtdMqlrTU/IkAafAzESXeAvaIAramsQSt3eYxpTMzcwHZlN4XYtM8JZkMgOqYr3f2pfI6g6nO66Q65SGMJECTYcerDg23rOgyLBX6BDqJku9Ey51t0BrP733HGuDhiZLpgd7tC6CeJIItfF4cQXYU1nADrGnyQfb@xY5TrI@4mdbmwK/aqqGNhPznOCE6jA3Q7kpIAcxENDFdAJwIrnUBTxKCKiiBiAz8NHtEHEHpXjsOgQn/SiUHhwKi740gJHG4/WDSvoFy248dDmvDybUbtDDFqvO8UbyNmN@llfxFse4Oy4oKX1h4cFPkBw/YO5AvHvembm9rlcyQFybbT/n/ksfZ0dZcKbdazf@wS8UQjK5VgS7fSeZDA4NCvtRwrwCSmyYehmCMIZ6xAmnIc@UOIkbKIjIrefeo/gNU/eiwBkez@ZIQT4fmZHAhSQEEckpkpAk4/UaD360ykOnoJ1xrKH08WUlaeiODQYfIEwK8aJDvKaQBXMDz8a9FBickOWYoIUBGP6OMUVzmHthiqzrISmWwgsCOkDtTSYdeTAkHRB4QWqNzr5DG22w6YEWV5PJY7s1dtVhEoFYnO7RGIB2j5pzLE7gr@0MB1zDSgygsjDVlEChfL4UFAX6qwdkZgK9E3FTEDLd63ce9/VvHhkjJRxYJBZt7zogdPdRsrz7i6yCPXNIn5B57ckzjPs/3OOBX7SH/iX9e3SQPvniOZRTSxqMMe@Z53CYYn3hI5/vUDnyHCrYHPnuOzwdfj4Ea@cx6Aq6FgAUOJS9JyDPYB2lDpWTQ@7Uc9hPhY5IDrj1@bxfIMMvDTr45ZB7pg@/A2vCDzG61Ts9h4YXdwcmGGSfgT7cQw5pP8jMF48LucjDurj4Q8nnwzQEDx8xAb@k7xs@Mq7cN2gy8z6xjVx6MHHUyK6tsm6JVw8fWwy0o4/XGj1KvKStDZRHB3j7SbI9afvso9/97oCNwSTqUyzsUT@Fwh@PDtDBZxd95NJdX@5zM/cdJ4aCTw@1ca124733gES6D7JVFxtxoe8ROqKpA/qI@TFO0z/88ANYn@juLHgWfPDeBdwPd57FWTx@5I8ljvyf3aw1iYYJGct6PaGQl0b3DXQf57gjXyT0WTmRJEkz@n34qkP8XCNYYiksJR/g42Frbnc07G58j59r@PTpI/yRf/isb/HvRxJjRxOQ15@PXuR5WlAHZ4tv/jzCt5ohwTbNsiEwMVYHLMseLMnfIw6z7Af8OHrs4@cPwAfBRz7Hx5/J5Aa54gmXqpIbNATwKFIPYDhcCKiH0CKAP9QB3@TwH2r28F/dxH/tMf6r8/gvM8Z/5RX@ow5@mUr5fu4nGHx0QtTBD6c/pP4RH1IX4CNMSg7Ozh6en32Bu@D3J76TE/zF/9ChneAJ@VghIOLBF/Cd3p2eBs/OFmeBh7M76uALdbB4pg5CLpC@@yPqILU4rRNK73JnNs1P9jy7DOHTwMNdrQy2dNMfOg0chArprD/UaGUOWLiLbm5xYhjf1vPpXLUF0LVyPt3In5fa@VYN4o2Hx7PPn31BaIHPwbMHoGTxC9@ZL2WaJrp9PAqidz@Pe0LWLXWQO1u06MApEFu2Y@qkmMA93N17obAfqYO7gzvPp9CnECMzM4Yds@Mrtbr5r1YhXlowI1VnhsyQ7YOYIUZoMUtmuWAmapXtQ1CAP2YCQYkRF8yAURiFZReLSDVW/byD7u3/SVW9qqqAUYXc5oIxMXJGhOugWr0CnCKUP4I/iWGYBdC5YGbwz8hE8tnvHxlSay9zf0/dIdcPAuiDIOsOMu5gzO2WHqIx7enLcyj2dEeshWjy4U5YSOaDC/ndj/d3yWTS/XByQBv397SlIl2hiOsEgzw/Pz7m0s304yONF08Wp4e@z77AZ/ikznyn9uXTQf/s5NP9cQDLtyXjwccD@vTT/RlmOYRP6Z/dV9ao4PrxnnJ75p1OB38789ncCpGAFXffWafinw4NUVYI38zhM3sj/25g8VrIPJ676MOXZ6/X@@HefeK2GOTxIAFMa4@LvV@ERBRyeYnNnYQBiw1jsygW9Z6dxaJwH0t4Ax6GJFtZ7l2apt27gmQOHySOO6lUWte5JQGKwJh57@L0x3vXXeghlUpGSXQ0kIwhVQ8kw16X1/s9e3pqlxHyQrTLvXCpuht9ed7@83x5PvWQjxf/eb040v4983og2RuFu8UXz@LUc@rBcRCFc315PsNBAvcFQnce74P3@dmKg1@P99TCeeYFvuGFin/Cf9VAhobcB88H2NZRUCTq9fSWgjcS8yR8Sfsv9REq4HGF3WGol8vNue/uPh@Fj@KRu08PRw9HntOj4NH92cPOSOJ1HyDoIo5Ip9gDzDfqIHhSd7EhlxuL@AnecVBlISirAxROnuwKg/vRc/Tyk2CTviPf57ujZNIq@@jox4/QGwEdFOaCzwHIL/Kg07PTtVCtMS68ZwD7BdlMhvDzF5AzKxFMJ4@9p3B/v2BIN/eik17q8MsB93xC8KNnl/tkR14Jfo/7hGw6ub64Djn9jn1wPbsOv/SesY15xHqJKRONnJwcRaxwPAFh9shrraNGGbhzwpAiGBxPFMLJARYnN/DcC7VK9YSBpIBducMkXzQapUPwu/hFLB9aUCd4c8baCXIFXFYHQokkwXeADCNJwTSmBy0/R3EGxmUZP5SgiuJHKx7mY6gnCGASC7KMVxXxdAWsdrk/hynyR@oA9BeYRoYAn0mNE6aCMJ9O58L6k5WMY26EPCOYbuPPT7/@g59@/T/@9Js/@ek3f/DTb/78t7/68z@A79/A90@s65/8h2QU//72V//L//bTX/0GIv8LfP8zfP/Tb3/1b37f@pL7v4Pv/70V93f2dwvO@lKA65//9ld/@te//dW/@Av4/jv7@xcvvz/92X@0/v8f@w8Hf/PTn/0d/rFv/uBPqL//21/j/z/927//z7/G///7//r3f/uv//6f/3sS@Esr8P/@u/9g/ULhf/7HP/2bP4Q6/RkO/zMIwz/yBayPzwb4Ixz54yEDViK6/3Eb8keahaEH0VuRf4R@vMdukewGEvD/2x9pBgZJxoJc49yG/OPf/upf/TXE/vgZQZwN@YdOdluGdiB36ISC/ggg/2oL4I9@@vXv//TX/8NPv/7Ln379zykwduH/I/pIhRC@4h@KtdB@JKHFERUNg5w6YXYTDkdIOAq/@ywOvAXz6fNOlIX7aB8wAfxE0j/uNWBwGUcObfsK@@jk34vhE/oMyTBmkWFrgX/xDcTgMFF55OJELWxAcm/B2PdbOa0Y6x5tZd@Nx5FbGZ3LvmgrgRTpACEb2cIuFG3Q29WgHMos4MWrCArZ1aOoOGrV4KdeOi82t67NfDpbpGIoU63kXlyiNlAUlfOF5vo2bqU6WaNrFN18ufzy1r501SniOaycyKEHC3IsUfD0lGWps0a@CRHNKmJDTJA6u0GLIKrVrg2XS6WwTvyIonG/PxgMwg@@@smHXIOH3zsg7NtW8AF1hfcHkqzlriHhHBDShSTeoAZVOleIf0APn30x1d6OhAuOwkFdGgxNZM7VNYBhGGBArW0rx65a21cd1OM4/P25HyhB2P6Y70eYVhkk7lWK/BqcKsKIMsEPoWPXJhPPlyURMVQQjz@hUDIRTSTDoYQ/kUxEomwsGvWzIT8bT8STjB9mygk2logmWX8ikgxHIpGkH5oxmoxTB4LSl0SahmkS63IhEpAUHj9deYofU1WDwzPqoC@IkiJ8QAtP3/vhoO9EoGkCucKJewa5aNrFxii8r3i0SIHFjXdcwyzoLhfl4hCPDgqFLFMouFwZfAPql8kyLlcf30QTDBPPuFwCSckmwkwIMg3xXT7GYF91l4RvsulCAWMY4ZtQAuNwucZWinUjOzdxAFPwTTiMESCX62mNjgHkqkVRguQyrRuGyWRdrqlFXgL@AC5t3UUIsXl8gxNwpoKVkoU0l@vcyQSjistVt@DsoopOfdNpl6tk3aTTGMUFqXzUqtQlvkmTD2TS4Q7E1@UaQGCgg73gcvUgiIXY5eIhxC85iJtACPt2Kibnci2teuCauFwLAs3xY5fr0YmHcoCeYpEbmn1hYH2WunXlIakESdJimi/0zs97g0FPX6bz53WSdHFR5EbLqd4b9OyMvUf4qDgXJI0ny5cfASc9PnLy/qRLSFJeJD0uHwVC4SP3BJTZnwEuaPJ4gZMuIGnfqoqNED4TAO7hT2YC1wzXs5KcD0ki10Wv5zoBqaVw/0FLj/cLmU56kCGtBFA7HsY/hclO9NM04YrFXcdHcHV9coUhuPAgxg3mq8t973J575IPn1zxqOvY/elTwP0d@wm54knXsSsedyHviSsEnS/qcsVQKO5y3YLFJwwCbvTJdaIL5lRXUOjkGVOwSjEnhBL05MFXzo9/e94vNljv5BmvWAOZT56VL8X60cr7CVMMszaY33qPSR1Onmn6FKsGFq990NQZzpOy1rgBLuFap1jKY937Ecxsg0EE30CAwulayuKDx5X0IDBJRQl@713EYrcWHj1udzzkdnvdJ4DkI3JtaXLvCaEVWTz1OIxxASuAMUmYYNq19yQDMP1BgSRQ/ookfXxsmJyOV6JJicfIFUu6cDQ@bC/pFPbZH2D9x0e96OnZf0dZ5niMpQ6eqT5@4jKSRCfJE7wmBPPE0zM7zyVaxge@4hbJJ9ShGxPtDu/Mmg/I7yE24Q4CYTWiHhweHlIHp80zV9hVDT6u1wLOaLKSdH92Ekll8TQfLLzg/ePpx5@/sIYzB88@O8thZ3jR79UnEqF0AftM9fF5fdY0PhHFfB0g4wDQnPj@IR8omUoBUuoEz/RcBxp0Ll5GS7zoiO6tip7@8oDM81Hti@PDMlXINtvxFd5U8XDHDfJs/N0D8v6yIslfEuHAGVmVxhKKoKWfG8nv498nvr9qVVvVwmfmOHGcuL@3m9PPulk3aSp7IewzDFVSPU8dGD961Sj7S@Xi5OBYc4cjbrB771MHVu3ZuPfgLBQPGtzy4MH2APVE4lhi4Z5M/kIsOhA7u5/5zs1sQlYIoajE7/UHAyn0e1c//HhI02432OGHZ3e@f9DST/Dx4CH2y8Cp9X8KPyhbtQh0xaIuL/arNb5//P7xAMEEELlCUdybfDSypnjbE1LP4kj5/kiBP@HIIH@CQG6Vo9MziDIgwr4XMITgPaJp@joEFkIyGUvEDqjf0fR7e9KQut6kEQVBN6aTfbs0aV264vAOlrLeqYHA1XQl6HB1DuFzTAmEbQm8DYmNie04277YiiJnV@7GLQ0ae8LhWIrCIYmciYpErKI8eInDJB5N6AifHIodfr3UF@oD4JryJnGig58TivqAvbnwrceB86PvDNOLPV0YL/Xhg61rDTNomI8YOc5kRwbYE@qZwuzh@n0D4Q004rhieQlz2DdK1ayHi@QlsjIZZDCxrCLi4IvL3SL4CIkWFVCbI0RKJJTjylnFf7DAelMRk1IolfOQB6WQSDZi7dwuvYfPiCLV@yh67cIRA1EYCwYnnCLgGBDQQaSH4PZOsCsy7yGQPsTidJFs6AIUWIl@QokfiXbGO3z7ANkxepGXVQMQW6V7rBqgo0e7WLsOzhCGKwEsxLUj4wMZ5/QB77dbDx@6cffgRV8ch0cPTkWnKLTxyLRxQWNYx7uSjPykbwkOOXzLZjPBxj74oWlPLMc5zxrOjtkw6pk6Mv2TE6uptBPq0sN7v@ANv5NfTr77jv9eu5s8nHgnKRNffb4JDFdjj2SBHJmpSQrEQ7uTHk5MUBHSQ2rivfTgexgJYWB/pkSL2YbXrhvUXEkBLdgpwPD6V3dK4JfKg79wp/iA5Kn/6Da18nMpxr@ArwTDvex/SrF2PaBMM7XyKSfcKXzx3uOOUyIM3T7uZCcKZxl75NTqjntIAT9kyOjzFaAyQKdxJ/t8D14oXIbE1xlP5O@@43zy2eJEDgS8GOr78KfCnQmBB18K3x97uNPFp9XdFPIfe@CagmJkLxAP@WxeP69pB/pOgMdWm25It2hcYPIWQN4klTq6/XR0e5T6@HF1twhMHvwW@4@ZjTRg4heY@JMtp0/P0a0XvWAJWXb0uH4hHf8ieGQgl1/y@YDJfm0rp0Xh0S2kaDB@2lQ/Y31JTp109rWxhNmOitYhXeQ4H7KuTQ7HNMiBwGYfu2xD3rTBS5INbvnaaxLMTDl8jKUfKaoS4AgETrNPwcWJ94tPnyinaNuLDkrGyqUHk3M8wyWHIOp4DZScqGw9pvU1/bpPDTs6dz2va5Ru8wjmkOHYVnclqol0OEPn7zAIVgNfmOcTS2NZvpOgbIj2ABiiPTBcAGsRzCRbT9iQKTsRWstpIMiF9YRoPfCCT4MysH4C9bbp@aBCLDKgM@8hQ/KPUkQ3gTxJEELSKSkPAtBVqA9QCUwDroP0gM5AkaHvvkP27WkK5sVxPBZgMAw38rEY6BWlUPg3UAo4MJUjkFGsD0khQNsHnII9fncKivzjCrId9j2QwTfyW377QeK375kqhvW4Cuab1yIDt8WHDyNfKmITBP/EXIf8kPb8uwN7uD8GY@Wq1mrm61fpBvzCfCOxOWj3eH0k66uDGDV8wGJPUoh/K8/VWaF7wYMJA8ajic/rwQcu99FFq4xCoUrOj5@uB9YfWKtPMKAerzEJBjm5zAiq@oCeS2OJ3j2pHR@OS1xpybnwAeekXEwOGZzlzUM0m2doDLy6BIO5/UjwzlndE8Ew7PMlA86R3eRYcvI40QQ/FQO90D6PkngpOY4WxK0HL//7ibOYLg0kcg7z0EKwk58cHWha2Un/oPA5kn3O5LBEU8kEwxwjxo8DrBMIOYGwE4g4gagTiDmBuBNIOIGkHWAdzKyFGSaH4XBsE4xvgolNMLkORphNcIMhEtoEw5tgZBOMboKb0iLr0mIJghcdONwkXVfQcRobSThp@CE4xSSRUUDDvoyMAKGhV5CQPfIqEspL7EbGk4xdUImuYqBQKLa5B@3jwKY8FlV@iw6/VbJ1Z0fCWEVZkyUisHldB62UX@CDc0HoYNaOHwqgKFC7iJcFDowBwQQrJVUA@Re8x9bDcvryePNgAMaQYtf3kB0fLAl5WHIGtCU@e5JD@5ItbKG92KynDdGaMVtPVdhEWlQe74y0FsbITtw21o9YwWKOvgERsiBwG@w@huGU2dSne4sMv1/kDsK9Rb4iysIb3ZcL88ZDkKecrGT8J9hSTnmWnSKQ1gYzwD7wn8jAiwbFT02mvrDHrt/@6i/@D/TbX/3pb9BPf/Wb/@8//c84/B/xz/8JNgsKrQH@5E/xz7/FP/8a//wV/vmzrUwEPnzs@ukvfg23/9O/Rz/9wZ9aSf/qr13@yBoRpOCoTc4//2f45w/xz//l8kfXgH/@xxYgzuLyP1M7ppUHoP7kvyAEpWEsa2R/8TcIuXxgYHhsybuz@vjD1jNWFoI1G@5I6OFluvXLD3XMdsbrcwFe@47d3PlwA3i3kOscPsF@0/fAnLF8e7GW5jl@iJ@jsaNUA9s/PDZhVCM4AHmb98HosZcX3FD7/x4dI7cPw0A0eVg0Zelwu/52vV2bVAzrc9FAHT4U1kaFw941JTC9pUC@yUxgaQTxtIXMSFlLRmz@VvAbMpwBxOVIlmR6WC9ll@XkhkkPsg8ah//NVBcLLR6GrIctyYH/lP1ICLtV4I66edFsUMrLGJgybh6/2s5KIoSJBk0C2db8xozFN4QL/pfoNi1nd5t8tfCiw@BPD0zM8bZGWheUQi7XV2Axp214L7a4wrvwFr02wB1zHH7YeZhrH7Dr5ubGRW3FMViG9L6HYNiqlKUy1knsblJoKym0lQQ0WziJromGQi9oIAMH1ou7Dy5a2bZU1G62jXDhnuO0AyYD5oLWuqJflKfGMPUaNdHIu8ruNfItlOxDyu4n9wrROWfI5X2VAXDu5km9bMv9qJlXMK8ban9OzO2dmJ3WehvTTp6tTkG4R73k0rrl2OS@ltst8B3U7IPvGwsKMf/IggLfWFAs@vWCXjYrzruD/m3@fl3tOGpireE3yKyOf7AzQOGh8S9A9DbqCFOsk6DHC1OetD3l6c1V5NlzojzE085xOjvHyOtbh@zgSUxFNQVreeCzpsKUQ8VW8NZraPa9Ssp@68tAUXXB2H5IU7IeeFHc@DFhXh0oMKr58bE@kv2OBLzfbR0IsTuurEc22wrNWm@2wagtRmHL8/FRUiTz8RGMT1n0bhiIb4M8fgrBTeFX4kBoK79nbdpWNY@KjyczvV/HSexdK1tT4seeqmYnuqGQNIIJHS/IMPlCQ44f45c7EZbgKpJHJrFF2jM9XszEoTpRB4Ki4iekce4X6Esb3JggTtMILX7E@RG/RZE9ifbwfs5rZ7382VnRZcjDedf5Q7sIdpjhR/pLHmPO6nuKe3yzOCubU17j59Pb2Ka38T69oqQb5kuaSSRe7cHXn1d02LPBAIAbMsJfJ8NvH4rwipwdUtbR@E0NVoZvJrEvGDwMf5jSNICmbfCgCPLhX98ZcLcmvP0W/99vQCd7/lubjxizjSXom0ke235kimaQI2EUXvAAeMmLdc/r4tainfvGsuyJDpnh@ZGLKC4FP8wCHVPTBMVY7/c6iL8i89gR55XcE@@clJW4hyZ95kfj0NtNlHvsCzK3FPoeG9K/hdepcV3g@kRffVvFsaIjSk@1Xs/hYfzsjilGHjokQMdviAznn3m9b4uVBSKtpYdsxhEKS2/zjyzcvVTNeBE0Ze2BqDpo0ANy2gg540VbakvrQWXZeiuYrUet8cdqyQp@fvurDAE@WO98Yv2bYr3vqc@6Z12lbxgR1rDB3SrjZxEdjPhpwNdt@PNY9PWaklWGdaaU08o71slbLS691@JbUuHIpGWVfJtIfk3ovlnmtkTNQrZRYdmfN4S8wpzlZJnnPdsYrZh3W0xVXukEHIdbTFXeGFUe9yjUdU6i6Ux8vHrKsi@8lATBElxncG3DFSOEOeijJVBO3bBd6yx5kZQJp21ZLXbMHY9t0S0uerf3EbegKCeMF3Kf12Xyb5bJvyqT3ylz3QN2i9wCovidIu1WwM3zXhPIgmi@oZ1xEp65w@U9tQ0fReV0vPf6xS25jyU/cs/cx6CQ3YL7OO8Bpezuu49zJGC4jxskMHYfX0Jg07fcP7qPnW6BAXS4JYHPON5W4fiedx9nPd5nirwL0ik36D5etynAfLJuCUeereXVnr3rr65XVQXBbxmVfoQlxoCLiqt19@AnXwb@Cah9hBckfkyh0BEBxhOQnUFja8SwyoFhI0heNufZN3wcO0tT9vrGZg0F0n2prUUVLCVToo/cB@5dZWQRhlPJ4iNcgUCsN4/3U4TYVzOzr5Fjlw4SShp5t3zCvSCxB/oekn4HwNuLOPImv9NeuyisBvw2OnHmt@h8RY5THKEIOwN495CFmfqD@51K4bZ@cRyU1frbLfR6jQA3YsABsVqJoN3S6WDDYduUFKap2q6QkFS82ydt58Efu1Ni6X2RjWgFu2e@kUyi7ZphxbDd@b3vVWcrHyZtRwXhxDvmwepl63GB6GKctNF1W5aq1fmAhC2d0ycnOQhYbHN2kMBZ6sZPxoq3hiEnr1Uk0Vy7ahIyB/EDa1POtErf7Mvgx9h@3vTVyQkmONCIEWzlXJdi6Vf1Z9jvqmW/Owa1w4QXBewzrPcPpa/N63dH2ReUy5tiXzcgTvSjnHevcbQuYcNymB1sWebvydorEx@/dccy8q1C19hfWPsO29Zzgq/w7eXcwsKFrQR9ths5xguz49DbjHptkcizoGO0BHFJNh6r4mtKN1V7n1ar4vuaGKfgMRouP7uB9d0G3m48jI9UQH/BcquX47cXkn2Kdd/Ga@pbOxfWroOKvcTWh5ttRYK6J/5raxctiKg@1nPVSrkLg248Hve@3orAvRbybsZx6t1tgvW0JeTHJ9mQdypj34mhqpsf7xXXa5cyEgHGAEf2bSzxs/u419ZlW/r8Rd@FfBbsFkdtXONNN@B2tBI2dTg8ZEs2X60Tnz1HnI3EMW@B334yW8O7Rlg68IbO4yMZvh4fsXPO46M9iuGmWW8j/e7AfulTaOvFyAe73kxvvKseLwBMJ9Zree0FOPsgCMsP5QC/Anv9pvt1rqliSo6zA14fwltUa88IT5j1Wm/OdmKsF1yDpHpCETyFDUXx879WLgyNFz6Ja6VdzkfL0MGnnBqaqthvwB5bb0knZ64aztIrIXuqzDniBmKVQh5b3qLIcshy9sXIS23JGdvWG4Q5xVpCdnjjR8IgSHZ8QkmYcowlzTrobO36YXhJJkIw8dECHvdkYYJfLAuyu2c1@UqCVhkWpMEABIm2jzG3HFya@F2zAVUMZJ0DPA5Qm7we2D4g0vYJI4ez2uvAwE7PzgksBgrFwJpK@oGzmy8wFrvJIHzKCkOctAgUfONwiVvBhH8r70fP0rt7ZZ2PF@P76HnELWs97yjp@MjyGads8dl@DHJradretCR6YGvn0jlMiLIPf0qRfcog9lHTPK4Dl3PEEg5abhOczDtnk3jwqTjH1AeFKB7sAYZ4y7cGDFwFG21ke827dklV0C9QOETewQjlESuVFAs4rJ29HeyQBlkxsZZ3n61gXL/ou36BNxOpDwdYF1qyhvM7oozD5KjIjSyjjzY6a0MFd2WrCzg30a2bMEw1Puwp@KPH5QMsPpfXtYMJ4O3djw@W5n2dFZSi93d0sx/rFNR0Ot2csHr9PD1ID9P1LtxnmLKvM4rkaTpflPvpXKm3PFfjzZkYYprd60wv7KvF@wtNKk6yRS1PSZHuxHcbXiSLkVU0G86meeZGPC@LkXj2RrwxhLQsJOnZaHzdF@paj9UN6bJyVamv6ELruj24Hom3nc4orjQorX6bGVwvhOtER5m1W8mScS20sxVzXBmZU3ZZjXdirbliZNrNzPBiWZqPF6WY2pWi2Wsh3ha14pxfRjW@2KJuZ81hrFFcjpPspL9MZ41@N@7z0d1sZpAo8v1b8aKRvewP9GgvOm4kufBsciFqy@FlUXkqj7KNGe/TRoVSbEYptdJsLkQ6455cVG7r7XYvl6nNx6xxq/VHkc7V1Owl9Fg4PE0Lw1EkWpqaeqKcSV/GzVy61C7IN23zdtlO1CizaDbjrQs@KftmVZMPT3Mt2mDaiwvpsjGPFUNNtahcyKVRbXw@Pa/J2nSci0jV5iSiD24KPTUUKl43ZsVumdIjF51uoj4KJXL8gqcvo6o6CTeTlbJ@tZhmnqpCJ8s3MkIvxmSiN3l2dFVd8tVZuV7v1LROaxI3Lln5tsCMqOoN30hnxoXyJME2K8tS4rzUmGazpcWsFxIHanra74SvbmLzckUoda7pcJGbmlc@KVuV6dHFhbFsty5LNxXjFrr11YUUEZeLTDuji0@5rHFVL9MVfTxsREZKX2vHpazKX9RKEbM0ThfnndtkKTMWxFpvrI6bHbkzNaXciC5Qy@z4utUT5gVpNefykXL7mh7l67wZTw/CDXokir2xXDVWg/PyatCY9gb9ZPWcyQlPl/1MO1rPa@xVwYhUlCXVbWZEaVW/FtlxLVks3fbyaelKiWZrglY7L84WoVBXEmvz6Ipd3IwKEWnBR5hyNXNz5bu@CNV9ZV8mU1PD1QEVyhXOO4PopU8tCCu6LHJP8axPn04ji9wUv0q43FJkfRKVmUSh6RvGDb2TvLqa94zSTT3b4eVV4vZqPI7d1qmbWclQ9VDiopBO0rUxo59zo0rpNi4phcg8cy7nk6XOqpUw8@WpnCiWB7mLup5rTvibZH7QWC7Hg8SFUCuP05SQyNXro96g3Vt0G0ZtyVxF@FHPlz/PV54G0I/bjULoopWJDab1cPsyp8xqzYJvpd50ylq2MmbztcQ01oyHJ9RscZFIN0xF0nLnV8nY9VQq59O5QSvLqoJw88RfsmOu0VwyCSOuXxdurjXDZzZ7aqQ3zISX11ddun1rGNGiRN0uOrFSeqzzl/2FeWHEm0pIrV4z7LVYacnRWUd66tbUUXpCX7ZuVnRvviosaiZvNsZqtB@Pjs8XxpO@utQvqUR3xMmtSlYtj/jYZVdaxekoqzS7WfGK716EmHRrULwSCsXZYNUSJqFR8Wla5DneqKW7vXM5NltoPjGcmJWpZqVzM4g/PTE9odJNSulxq14rmaEmR0@7jXL0qdw1jALfKkmZiKRMc5nu@XiSvV1yTWOxmjZjPVlc1vQQk6cWle5Vmx@pA6Ng3PKj1U3hVrmahmI31ZEYN/tjdiKx5bbIxCta3Zfz1eTz3mAZa0@FGQ@WoXZd0thMejSqUlV2Ep9llknDVM6Ny0ove5GW0ulyInStheLFcfa8uOhL7Va7UuxzauS2lw3Hqr0BE@pnKvlBLTIZxGuVeKScpZq95XWd7ecSEjvk5OzoYhnRkuVQJka35/Xi9ag5VCpyNt1ZiJkw31Tn8Q4nKi1hFYvTV4xvNExeKGkmUotRLTNntsqFedinXJauQrXlkr/pcdMwJz51DR/fXQ1X1bbAqfKw/FRnm@1pOSuNRu1Yhm8y1UyDma6MOaeVa1QyV1PYXHkxK8yHjQ5jaLmilugtKv1srSb0tH5YE3vV9EJkZp3O7fV1q6pMbq4nxXq8V131uVG0bYr1WHVhUk9g8rRn5Vaht8iJhjiqz56U88X0pk1HWueTcqs/842St91ZWLqpMuVKpi1y09L1IG62Kgvt6kIWZXoSqg5oat6qrVamkFbzlflVdyG2V6u0lDGe2MUlzZXPS7kb05fMF9K5arPB6XK1el7OpbnJ/Gpevon7hFXjqh@Vxk@3VE1R5JB@25DjGSZshFrR3CrLj86Z6Xlm0rxoJlmNbRXbV1eX7FDmJ3y8W83FOld8J52@uFxeiFy7VtNql60mVfUpN7e3TbralMtJsVyqN9VoaaZfdTpxbq6mrzmmFJn05uVFZn41nXYmyQtf1xS4sLoSBLY@l8u0UATZSVDCdFbLVmrGMvS0Gj0NZjn1pp1Ma@exdHYp9mfCbMWkczMfbRQW835M0hKhZndxLnb5q8Hgsp4ZhrWZ1oxlo9RFUrxS2r3s8Cq5FC6L5XZhagqNfi8i@QxGGzWv0y2jxS@lcz42nLWMrgydT9SizUw2aci3ucSlLvmYBJ@h@M4VV6PLw@hN5aKvzrOLq/YyB1OOBCvWmKi6VNrTxFgpXhqZy87TZSIxaPWKYyh4Orwd8lLLl@n3hGtRrlC3N5ftcb42bdOj65ureK1V9CVWYf38iVeH51xy2VxVGUYQk4NZaboIa2U@cZ64rPLyxaJSb4nCINYIXcvnyorKKfEhkxbZ@Wyu0L5lNJPID8RMq6LouRZfjAtqjaPpRefWrHZuEpehc@aaaUzmTMi4mtOM2FWkZbfS7Yb6VGZmXGqdBjvL@4pmutsY1flzma506qWVuiznQ0YrXcmKl9P5UisvJT18y5fPs3KNl1gwS6KxQVNvjVeZWY/qiItyNpOI34aKIEGGISfn3Qgn8IY2WIzo8tW0KC9G03Fb900WdN13211Ek8P20KD5crlZKc3zelS9MEYKFYvxoWJH1@JG/WmyLGXN3LDdkiPZZHvQqxa79FVTvExeZxu3cSFao0tPQrLTiDF8OdrhabauTmYmjEj8YEyVl0xf52VB5@LT6lM0P536@svZ1PRpt/Hzy0RnMM6yM57zhdM99YlbtC9kRqrEhYFR7cxnN4UOWIhKe9ZSqMJtSwtfSkWxUWxXr8ZsLV1fmXQm2eFvIoOuzoqKOKuHzehFSRjEeTGXvx2PcsXSU4npik/MnJX16@twochScdGXMdW@TLevtWtlFeKEdLeauJr3V9nJsCIKxVIop3frsX7jkpPzMIxKT2VGaxfOy7f9njykRVWpNuoMQ93GQvnOTf2JnfWva6umuijqg4t0TQ7fiCVFrd202dy1TlfimcJ1dlS/zS4TsZou94TmINFUJr7zsMpzaaUco@LCTMi0O3RLkMJsfLHqcWOBZm8743GiSK9ixopOK8Z8lBiskr3zCdu5rajnzeWYPp8sbmuZG3Yq@Fi2xmvUtbmqRc/PO77L5XmrNJBbJZGnuclyZBQzU@Fi3ruOpX0JjWn68v32cFGuDbROno73egm2EQ53IuZTv7Y0ritUO1cuhuO5pbkQ8@NpZZEoaulYY7loXUci49vRoppoxOrRBTtTx/mMVhhEafXGiCuLZnFQyAh58Uo0rlY9fkLFVtNKqZDI@6IC1611bxkxTz81@rI5HIjNy5twI0bz0WK1Nr@9zaXpSVwc5UvyOYyJc@5qsWyMuuPeddUIS5Ra7fpKsVVs1bi9rvSVWufiatibD@Lxml5sj5LTVVerS3WftmqVeup5rjaRc6sbELhYPRkdteR8qyPd5OpMlTJjnfQcbHA2U5aWA7oUZS5FhblYTM6TN5NObNwdt7OzencxHsUa8ag6FVZxs/MUnQqtePdi0qD5Xnc@9IXOKbWxWt7kryN6uTLXymZNFS6ZRKh8O25N8tOWb5K9LPTMbIfReqFOeT71ZaNgFSSu2slQpXc5ypTG59dG8TqUpJoFaTlNjM5j574aDCbTkVFNtOWQPKM7tNyez4TxhOEqOa6tL3qtQrlf6YcStOaT4nPzMvZ00a3dcqYWUWjKWMb6c85XzIMFkZO60YavbWrMBOYizM0sfKkMwiFDuWk0eDOrxsetcFKIFPS2orYX6qgdkq7P4@M5L12OqIyw6kfkVr3TryxW835yHOlzjVkrXbhROuGsog0Xhs7GkpehNvdUm@jhqqnVyi0@o1xPOE6c@xZyJnelN2ZUf1BJ9zuFp6k4a0eq6Uh6edNnItPb2YhVVjf5bmhU66WH4rzeiazq83Cmf84q9YmkTfQQzTTbSn6cWLSKwiV1scoLy2HiOlNrR1qXo@Q4LA/GjRqzHFclkb@9NaZsqTsoX7P9UrSduU6Oi6KRFuKtpHgxoheVXvU2lu0LEYbyDUsTOpQt8@GL/I3PvODl6JO0YivmKikqy0pL6jUGs7RW7o9a00qmSGfY0Ox8UZ2Ei3U6POUyk0TuUu/qMiXko@lFq3oVM4a3abMdUWuhWUK7rUmDm1C/NuT4CRNLgA6@6vdul610PTMvdyvFhpFWBivBp88vlfNSoZBRqKLYqTwZT5wqTtORVrXcvX66TuuDZrRnGiV28STQy6VSvcjy/LKbLhnjSvuioZTizKSfuYpfD/tlpaXWpPAlxSfj45s4rTT4iykjRGrpSOGpfc4/lWaxujpWTL6Zv2XNSh2UXSnaqmrd@WSVHTLiIhzJ3xjVQV@7hd46WlGhabHe7dfFkbKY1y/M9mV40mDH7bk8jimc5ovkk9Uqxw7CeBIWvVGViSpfDsybRmV2qdP0cBWbCtq5cClR5ZA2SJfqsYsQd37ezSVb7OSpLIQSV5Fpeh6q1q98SlTQcqXBRGay4/pIuJZgytCJ1UYXTKMitQa30@xNctmgVt2emFQuOnP1Mjue58azUbO1CMP0qtkuG0ajfmP2S7NQ7yIu96rDfjNXyF7zWY4z4lUlm6@OtWm7N5kXI1FqVAjfjK7iF9IgNo6XhGX3cqolaxerUnZYjPi6ykXC7HKm/FSVR0@Vnmn2nuJSu3F9QXcycV5hnpZx82bYoQ2qmJjkzyNCfFUasvGWMplNp/1qXVFLy9r1FbA5Hgo3z3t0Wutc18x2vyjwN8UWWPoXqlBq3FxojfObYn/aVyg5DOKbpfXL87JRuMmNb9l5qb7sSaxvXL2cV6PxqJjs@WbRSWU4zUWjnfjkojIr5DQ9trgCrT@oLWtloV65otjJVTc/9l2ILJvQr1btWaSeFm5ivau5OI9Ec@mFMkwkWszi@uKcv070tNJ80rpgB9f0/DY5NiZci6uneVWsUpknLbzMLcw8E81fxoo318IoNu/np6FSet7olGJmsiJ2OpGneX0@FioFVmwuZvNQrVC9NpVIdNG@vh1fQitEKX6wuM7HhauI0Gek1W1WL6g9pcWlGfqCDs1b7WufOlCeKoJvXAsVwloszyxqHMyMbzPTi36s1xrJnfNMMTmk@hE@72sasdJt7Onm6UrSb0a@@ARUTkKsz66vwCTpma1mZHEtJrvsqp1NdLheYcXmL@l0pFicJkuh0EU5We5SRiM6AWl5moduLnJy6LrWbkamvlwlt@gPG7etenZ@lbjtspNapzG7wJOxMM3Mxeqo3lpWCouWJMTy43pezFC@0vXcqCY1sZ5r53W61hcLkdG4eF44F6aX/HSRV3zMoNRazp6mEyFxcSVzgq4U6uYwzYe7iXF4wZe09NNlm1oWufwFm020E/pY4i9GlZYxMmYdTZTSkafowmfWRzXpMpqrN2@UUWtYqeh89ioUN4TcuDGJ3bZGi95MyPcvKNFMznh5cV6JmUpmWZBuWlfXF/0Gs@RriYtKQV8wPbrw1GBmJt1KNGrNQa@iS@URDJy@bktVEzKoFHOoXlOcNiwx83b6sp8YGNlzJlG@WFRbUsXHXOfro1zImOk@ejiphnIrNX8RFufxQf36csLo2Vl/6LusxenbUUadV6io2Q93OGOcrItst9umtXx9ZRhXiVbPd3kt00I9dBvPFFdssxfW@tNhN9GdnM@eut2rp167UYTmvPEJscbVEzW4viwacTHJs/1WJltOqzONudAndTEyKavdVqgr@rqLXGn@FLpkCqNSj61UhqtVhr/QO0oiN@ldZbnlqJVoU@F8lenfhgXtopV76haG0xGfLS/48I1aNHw3kcpieq4n4jE2kpxxRrg9mbR9ibQs@eLh4XIYyuRnsRzd1@sdKl/1ZTuqCr2gfhvjKrQR6Vdk02jFm418sp4tZIvly/yNWE42StzNja97Xcrm083YxeVwHLnsskaGzlwNR40QNSpnx33aNBNTqSEVjPy5nlsMb8fXk2lvHp@Vje5KueSm0mDCipw27pSVeCx93X6KVplw/orO365kJRSPLpJUnxf7F7RcH990ElK@SHflIUygcyD/45urqc6LujFMdqDmVyslnm1VB229KA9rQKHcm2q8OElK46EQvqXqdCNRiHfkS5GvduuTeLcn3TQvwnFxuoD5aze3uhRzNLR6q9sYTpmbWB5M10jkqdQZTq5nlbZRj@bazXItQrWf6jmRLeXL5fat2WcrVWZQmJmteKKYZ/lJZlzJLzO9TGle4Fudom/kCzX7/KzQTsv5dp8zFstbJsnoaXFExUaxq4yYY815tC3qkezFsBrm5JK6qF4ktEm9dhHKXOSvRXWsM5nrtPOJtZfJiRRdDsR0@rxd6mYHVPo6mxuF2qLB1xXfvETAMgWZ@93PPipE0HWFgFEzVeoj8nJ0@5iLk3cOniAnT@DH23fOncDOPtsHCYj289VAC5Tjd7XwE8LHViFkbzOI30WAtxZPXu4tBljnOAFywed4oCPy/gFxZyPUpePMazI@Ssp7BJAdT7KDgvfByOPJvzCO4Qs0@B2UwCbyRJ2H8Mb7VdoIR/A5H/iMTObhZGvL08NuU4MJhCbjFBH46Xf9Ap@q8B1kJFvA@WrBu29bnznZyQ/EGZpCThpxBYIuktU@FQNj2kVhtSaOX5/NQJEDWZyNtXfersTRbIKJJcn5Hkjxm/7JXfLBf8SnXEgwJU6ZGFN93h8P1OFMRDLSRr0Fv1w9IRSNoDCUFfrOOkKTjaVociJtHH4TKMnYx0NZJ1iS84rwIVnkkEN8YKYbocD6iKmPyEsCfvxz7Dp5JaXoaOJIoXXIx@Qu9pBSUszJ5E55OFF8Pq/pS5k@1ufBEd@x3hNtansi3pkP5Kl9@ghdOY/W43cPYN9fVUQ1VeGHqttA5M3E28@ckMPAnA404bTt/jQTeFPVt2NELE/cZKcjvo7Cu8Tci5yS6sCZS03AW3frUwlk/E53/PNhGoucvE7HNfzwAR@hcWL7TmxX4AulTXuyxB9THwg/8RY4fpz@@Ng@FIZHWG4/fCBxkhVp0YIkw4OTT5xUXtWWdmbJAnl06nK6hfLMg/dWvf5vgXSgeiCTj/hNUTqAWSAWe3fAEaAmW6NeiyocLgvKeh8Un@PjPcGnnKCPTppz4g@Gx3JDzt15NJFETumByymyQckZGMhrnzhBYu8k/NAbcSU4c1tJH0bTiUb2n4MWvTZH8MstHzVO0tc5g8YUv0LZg1jMDMkhGrcADjzj89hmnClsN43TFtjxjTx8heuD8dXIu0yAYJ7T9SXWjfjhA4yvr5I8H6y3p3qQqVqOlRYZdl5SDa/d1MA4fF60W3MfI@IHdwJRZEv0ZCt1BKm4rm8kTyB5wpnDN5KHGPfUeCtZh2T8TtU3kiVItp6J3J@uQrq10/8GgIm9PEFcH0310eQk2WMd6IGPAnm2FLYH@XwOY9cigKyGsdpjNz@yj0ZBH63WsYRtR7ygfxKxsgCwSHvszoPvN9JCUvFx2h5LLrbKtHiCvqCvFmY7RwKLH0lJoHZx@d6jHfxoiwDof6BK0et0p3CrtdcV3ZGfIAw7A9zawKww@vHH9yizBXFX/tgHR/qsFsJ@uFs1tLi1wWO98nHTrlamlZ1pfx776Jht7eb4SGzq4XTK0EaFWH1r069FSelDGYD443Y0dnnyok@bmDvjAR2vtceGj1a3@DofQ6@kB3tEkR7pR71NkP92rnJY7iEnByNyb6Ms8Dlh3Mkrdhpr6MAu9BlAr7n5Qs74HZmxe@nPrey31eYA6COdmvDmxFK0PJiGZzaBe8jjrHbd1gkWskP3sRWPX2Up7SKT3kBmnaf3CAjMU6ABj2yOGnfGREkJWs@kgp5nQhE/cTG3QJ43bHKU1bfw6Z@gc2HG2UP2FL/da1cloT2seQW@rjfm19nLLveiepam31@5O@uhZvcnN6YRvZYnInWfYJQ8RgxaH9x0gp6/rof@YZz5smm@HXvH8LytK5xGdyTxW0Tw@Q1Gf1XIdqsQekA7HMckEM3wlSGJHEK4f1DauNY/OjGO26XVt9@0wDBVJ7vpmGYLoZMAhvJ2Lr9tc51tVKd9@uKj6Rg3/o0Vhl@qaUkFmOwn1LY6x9O5Ahm8t2PXR0cRjmyn4CfZsYWpO5RJomPbghns5Avyj7iZLSZjfkKfHqhq3@MYTLbBQDA4J3QAkN86zmptVlnm5aZ4KM42etHAPuXDGXdPIOajHUXGFYjAxqctm5iIowHpNie422zZN5JB3vlK0vFoBEX9/8Vd/1caS7L/OfNXtONLAgkgmNzd@/x2g4jKOyouYIzHuAnCKLMBhsOAyLvJ375bn6runi@Auu/9sOeeG4fp7qrq6urq6pruKnP7AIcVRfuorfR71LYm0KuljYzGR0wyjlyp9TyvxAn14FbaQxwMxXDI1nrHxXs7EKizRxvtKL4lj8GvJV4GieGpo1v@Gd@6@Nt@ATaxHXRzCjK7banZ2XGBxgr8r3@ur21Mw/HGrT/c8IYPZFTfzp115Q0l1dmWmk7u8r/joDDS2Wttwuey@RAiiQmNFLAVht4so1PeI4qom3UkJh0fWiw5iAPM58b73kOXrH6J2DIKwkf@d06bhWJhOpoEXKIRcew69dP/GcVTLfItIr1j0OTsMJyoTgb3C@TtXM5K5ktiIJUQ5DgbA3GNlqxw3a@ui/EDofo86fWNExa8dqcHIiB7P2U7RcPFkvzLCc3QI9YaWIHLK/TYlygTIz47ChRsnYRz/k3dx@8SHuQNH3GF3Ot9isMHglHSD4IRhBxHQdF@hxggjH/VbB1UG42CTh8jJ9Zxyl3OMeOKIAes4/wH9hgvTqsjXKAMyit0FrAF324EnPUv8whoNZswFWZgp/AK8QilB/kS/1rohq2flerMEr7upH@F4GVRR/UYkR0F3kXNMrFmedPMVI6x4tWz3Gh3OggEceoNAqK44vX7RLTw4lXEDjyCIwb/e4s/vAbOG0u8lOcXyvOJ8oKUC1FRrUKnN44qbcUruet/RvV@KTeqllvAtauo07Uzji5VCMYxurefqhsWaJPmR5X37FCKVNqCnURBPlby9yWjLyVriTZWwG35tZRr@d7UI2@pTNT9lMSPv44eII9jMOgriykpLQz9/h/ifrQlrGEVwipJc4w3i51MSu0Q0eokT2qChJin7d5uBOV9yWgcnjPu3s4nt6BdUn9k0mRI3rOFibVkjsS4xDjfM@MeeSUhPFy8FgPBMCFoyszcPdN4rhvPY2BRa82gdUyk0OQEp66lp/gujnX/xD9msieJM/XWlxe@EsofpfNy0yLJIFa6a@5yNiW1yWQ89eSl7tQTq0iEe56GuFxJnAXYgXZ60BQWpyf3Qe6C6bC7ZvVEXFEYTbHAd1uiOR1VKBnxXTWEKPzl/HPjnXPUHpBV2PceVRk2dZtD4juJyzYTL5yENAc86uBYhdPRqO/ruG5qxtc5pJ@lzd9wGSGCGDMaCk4NF0Slfg5P@nIMNSqoOiDPcM8wKgin90j5DE8wsheTar3zCeSk4JSHc45MzGHQNuXKi6emiOMKBdynbV@MCBk5mT3seYCVVnDMxSLp6p3M7@GETCDqeMAxDxFqdctx/jb1Oz8qR2qzWPxrqfihFGOZcVUXCx8@qlrMRDIFm8VSsfhb6aPjVILRXK42ZjpZwPqYB8CcOsFC/5lk03tAdmGnTCsGVwzJ9A@98YPXLThOw@uyD/h2yhyBKE9DT6Ioc5xXvCHbCvHuydwdhDlF264e1Av@Yn2W2LUdDqyRc3CHaOSNB/5EbhoFD34XDDT3pu6Cfj@YsSMaV5aEH2g08CbElHdZlSSJ49JqWth24XCxxA0kV@AAfrfBA8eR1mwgO9VH@H2@AOQgiCIgxJFJBvUYJYSv02/7A4jTEgIQZSnigCGAutaddrwnaXCYiH@TBqU71g06U0TmbZuR2SDtF/BcoenujX3SvhGDeVS4WYx2GuDWca2pmvXD1mW5UVX0fN6of64dVA/U/pVqHVdVpX5@xTmy1HH9hLRLU5XPDujtWatR279o1emFW25SS5cLnPLZlap@OW9Um01Vb6ja6flJjaAR@Eb5rFWrNnOqdlY5uaDF@iinCII6q7fUSe201qJqrXqOsZpmTtRO1Q/VabVROaaf5f3aSa11xRgPa60zIDskbGV1Xm60apWLk3JDnV80zuvNqkLHnINas3JSrp1WDwqEn3Cq6ufqWUs1j8snJ6mO1i/Pqg0Qn@jlfpWoLO@fVBkT9/Og1qhWWuhQ9FQh5hGBJznVPK9WaniofqlSd8qNq5wG2qz@7YIqUaE6KJ@Wj6hzTuYZrtC4VC4a1VMQTZxoXuw3W7XWRauqjur1A@Z1s9r4XKtUm9vKOak3mWEXzWpOIecloyYYxC0qp@f9i2aN@VY7a9GacXHeqtXPsjTIl8QYorJMTQ@YwfUz6S0xqd64AlTwgQcgpy6Pq/S@AZ4yt8rgQpO4VmnFqxFCYmIr3k11Vj06qR1VzypVFNcB5rLWrGZpwGpNVCCYwHtZJqQX3GuME9EljySsjpHcHA@nqh2q8sHnGijXtUkCmjUtLcy2yrHmOc3lDWfpJ7cnP@AtfuXTrpCng8RX6gdVsvgkOYsbvb@gRef35Me7RBktNLaQfuqvoLxWfet6t9P7b/7wLsDW3DaTL9iD8D6HFEVZZBz96jyRS1l/KOcG6@vfvn0uf6N9bvPbt2zuJS0TZDzXQkdhfapWVvexH7S7vM1P@JbijNp7o2O95yTwctzX8sY6H7JqY6Pr6Wa4vAjAxk2kkxIQsC40I99qbA9VDCV/Yk76ijhjRtpZZD5vBiH9M/wZ/ZC1IfaClLOcW9jYwB6WyUDmE2XpJyScFERnBuFzAP4doyyEnvfjPlOMo8OWXzuosqYN153QNvA@k32m@a13n2qeT7dnYnHXlI0VEw7ehGmHYAb8S7NM6XEpjLlnGXHt8Z@soYYRkVGYFVR8kVWfPsm8keaILyq@wuy2DSXO6UBOy19ql9jMFTc/bqfeH9v3Mrdw6xy5bWi9u@Z2N/zn@EYq0ATzsf0ilvhz@aS6sRFrQ1YZ25O2MmLV91Bp5ndpTcVS3fN4WUeEfAkXHG9Pi/HYf4xTT2r4qFE@3b84PCTNCWo//v7bX/@y7eiI@@PJl5z8vQIepJVk7pIVPfPJTOOi2CypkN1zuJAsJ5bdB6OHikjpaAaNX7bJpLWRM8VGkPwa4gZCd0NkGBgiyYaLJAFjV@F@vrfmGHldOjO1AGQSXc2iN4P2I1v4bTKVWAY6EiWzP@dRe8Q/gG2nv5nitkNagLSIeYPRZE6SS5sL1nvuoQk4wHsbvlaMKgXXyPGobc4gCWOgMzkKA@7g8y8t27FRJLsWA435ysPOLYmItTQVJkkLp1wiFOdBaGawvPTpzRctb/R4pZMDoQipHsqTJrHx0LbMm@Q94nPWE0NDvtnbpSF688Zi2lFwpGY1UeL/T6aOic8GJkUONKgUYHPyyPLZlrAT@tPbrPpTJBVRvQFnW0us/k2Su6w7Gsq2CYmuf5sMMkpgRQll@NXM4nBMlStTxbIzwab/Fz8Y/n@QJ0vg79CGk6BH3GI97A@n3gs5yVCFV7R7Zab4M3NiLHZMLeJm/NVVBOZXfGB6tmP6GN6jfFgiFujRmZsXV5JSLLOEARBy@DXi8xcBfHkS99q0c/rEc/eVfOkfDzuDUcYk5DJLxQLcmxzbXDlzRA4/svIJv6hi6E6QX@UTx3lknYENF2mx27l6HboC432JdQ46vfGOnR52lrNogg0lM8MjcSrqqWUm/6M@YRStMl1T@otM0dXJvuznEOQUSih88wXEKBA@@xTvsGYb4dwDoUv7jUgv7OVXehVHxkhSgbwuqxaH5wjbd7xnxlKkY2kgaAdQAs7rrs7ZdOtNZlgu@gKdY4hE0FTmNYcxARLti7RmhFG@2QJxnRfZmaWe3ZSQV0v9xfDHENmMPXFxmRqFRAaoeAjWgjptczKo/sv67UbI34Ote0n8tSHHVenI90q45njnTliw038dRhwhi3MG65LWoYhL7c4PvHSNjPqzvP9IfxhXXvfc5DSiPQNnrFtm9P9auSGArKTOwCr369A6kbZkIdt9bcwXPMnctU9XeNJ@5l3qFBFHb3BgVptBIBl2Ew5pLs42pi8RVgeHT7fIcprNCrft6aA9vGsP/P6cT53@I@gNN8LhNBwVRnPHdd2kNxCBwBEihWifeOrSH3aDWaj2aTrAkdQ8u2ieJx1/Mc9XRTxfSv0P4VD7jNlZAH@HmElhcDehofG21Vyn9x5H7h72E2pPC7u15niBwFRjFiDCO7CW8dHZhTryht6Y7MFzPnOpTvyONyT1QcYUn8IMe6JpUP0Q2JsauzqE7cKenW3l@ezUsb49RyPQ0HIQrQxNRSJ4rNMqwjc/J1GP@QQLix2O@tU1TqVeMNLRgOA0hbEpLs67aT/nIHfjZa11jM24bMzZN0PLmvH1wZcoptNAnLXUmXF7OJkTU5y084bIfs53U1AcDIggOqvZyZu6AbKhd@H264fUVeRm11qAVxCaqp7/gGRx7IZ7yRjxOVvtNov4tq3jK@YkfZ1RHYnRc6LRyyFnaCGnfvtv1fIgu@q83@7QDks1p2j@4QPZgftBOEHV07JSxc1SqZQvfYCL9qJZLvBEwP8mg5jj1E7P640WMVKHyDeCYddMMJ@TdslpLGJHHqm7qPffoZBNfdKYm9@ZeTDBTRxfd1u@WLhbLo19pw13L/UwTJrD7JKFSz4Yc@IwRIMiEUpMR8KKoAdI0cdKEphi0HOcukwnH5OlxdLJ0fy4wXfQ1ie56uN76HduzO9IAXiP/I5ajXln0NVh72lMBt7AUu9PzOrelgpOOueZZZj4Ukk43ubewkoi7mXjcLoezkiEyB4wCB86Y9It7QcSORxhMSGxSGZYN2Vtb9q3ft@nOUB0dXoBFhxRV2Yg2AURz4jm8IjbXDtYkJiWJdkKaHZ1g4GtKlQ5jg0Gp9@PwnknUOv3tM3GTisceV6XMyVMR5IKAOUFmuV9WjkkTNxWlCPAWS/yuckxKRukZCHdN@0jdixi/d3KmDumNyRVJrxgq4dtvQCiHjUnPEmRsS2zZIedU/jOm@Vhb5NAoG0WjFgR6I9AjHL4KEVU0XizQPATi0sO4aj6PN7pOIBoyMmIwlGyALDkq66XLDDg0Xf9uFBBhHTXEpAKMWiIkThZ8pzwgSV/oL84d4qgaRnpI3VunrXMPPSRQlN8A4G6D/AvKhcMx@QbocffCBcCFz4iJC/BS9csLdakWjaBSKzm5hKY@aUwPyyHmdcw9cfK2vCBA7ahFYuF9EKiQQekH8GIqPtHgVG9HFauH8gHJtv7@35wi7xNpCkIG/7Mc9HAxl/zDizB6HipBBFM5pvaMV3SpOu7TcZ2UTs0P7w9tWM8FntfhzJQumBX5hLHLFO8dvF04kf8o2cUP7qJ5FWwOlLZq0CevCXdDbCuBqnfuFsqmpk4iROvrzEnmwwSTUqpJpq4ZJPbRJNNJ4pUmhpdtIDqx99kz4xdwqeSeATUrh2gojNoP8rupsgB6NhNg5SRiYh4mzdaQFDxuqNsTDtUv3GiEM2Jz/aCw/zkI3h84tv9L5dTXhWT@Q4ezdE9VgNcK1E@5zDgw4zuUFazgX/Y8M9ZQ4zu1w43GcY0le2wFDiJbo9xVysTx5LdUuujtnw1RK0QC1sc9TXzAF/pXfrvncpoBPk4sVIJYXW1KiTGc@jla9rKyrAYPVh0opWZf8UUHI2gI/qbj4zJMpDJJOaV0dwWpjwu6G4ChfcCjjE5Ev8zJLtO3mJFiamGJgw@pDHVRp73SNsz/sbMIHj9sR5r/VJiGlvtoYm/jjDfmFUj2YuVtdNLybI6sVXFcuGpyobZlk8rK69ebZh18CFA30n1GOtO4CTWrDNL8NtQWMZWij/hYKdBxxcNlWRbTOlK29wSBZwcckNcLtUrJxbKXPcwvYw4iZUzISSZ2C@kaVevJZGdAMo6iVbg/6oBx3HH@MReWa8k9fSwr5IIC8uM@1NiYSubcX9KLKRybNifFguTy9Cyltun5SIxEsICHErUOwb2KcV1kCl4jNd6TNViguY38VjmXj@zhNqYVtW@TmfBVLIs0qlLkjj4z6MMzLoONJoQR2LetR2Nm6i3tMZ1fnhdG5FZ995ukfbc5JIgo5lORIBOGww8RjdZpMy2DUhjixNM75kHcnaTI9q/lQ0L70GRteu@l7zdmwBrVpVidtGgNNH7I@J3lhKfX8yiEG2xthbzw9vTZZpqHHgKxl3Udp0lX3ydZ6h6H6Mq2bvYCCVZvAJS/kWQ8i@AtBGDpCf2B1ov@XF9jDx13nMgvn5dhMF//k4bKQ2DNG3XhxMb@@BZe/4czDUyttb5TF1bTpXZBpGd/ByMP9IwOC9oz36N0y97bXjd/tcbB@msHCs5m5SVJRRZqtYXycqBLNbavN/V9YypxHvbwo/bnm93AuvPj7TEMdaNcZS4Zz8CrSej6ltg0fwvreBfLjasyfkghCfcMGQtO//mdCiAEeJhkqtitkFMkSX3obogyYinS9PKj3er6ejHSHi6sln22Z58EodPzOlUoq6JxkpInNnCRcrJrFZGvy3bnj2Lf30p/lEwIhvnbikBXH8AP744pVIqPTJNU1vrF61lS9ezxX7F7bZUbpKXT/I3C13fpK7jYjpN6qE306v/U5B1X8wI/B8s@WsjIyuIfL2USHxob2vnlhpOB7fe2HnJVJcWBfyRPdJqyXWc9XVV7tCWWUfGh1esw@n7PI0SZjAEIVTTEb7XhHK4E5MbPjJPBDhdtxvMhly74AIF@2gHXnuoQ@XrBfN@jO8Xtm4O6TtxuYsx@MMOMTr0Yu7P75KTuuvpEpxIfoKt28vHHlINnJqKXIRJkyW2Zmae3NPK2xUGjrVquNZW2lAxsoOPoe/EMtf2Ehnm2eUusJdYT08ZRCTEq1DqDW8K9NMyurWamdORZaUdmhewcpm5Zb3cLzC35i81t/4DnEwPqBN71taDXmC3nlVq6U2@8y8)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))
- Gaot++ (140) [local](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)
- Floater (141) [local](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater)

### Explanation

Floater is another image-based language.

Floater path:
[image]

```
push 7   [7]
dup      [7 7]
mul      [49]
dup      [49 49]
dup      [49 49 49]
print    [49 49]
push 3   [49 49 3]
add      [49 52]
print    [49]
print    []
```

Dark blue `#0000AA` is noop in all other languages except Braincopter, where it is input. So Braincopter should now be called with `< nul`. 
Fixed Braincopter by adding `>` (black pixel above yellow).

Hello world from interpreter distribution has a bug: column of pixels in lower left corner should have color `#AAAAAA`.

Interpreter can be built and run with these two commands executed from Floater-master\src directory:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" org\zomb\floater\*.java org\zomb\utilities\*.java
java org.zomb.floater.FloaterMain image.png
```

#### Refactorings

Refactored Extended Brainloller/Brainloller, corresponding ebf/bf code now is:

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]~[>.++.--.@]>.+.+++++++.
```

After executing `+++++++[>+++++++<-]` the tape is [0!, 49] (! is current cell). `~` (bitwise not) is then used to separate Extended Brainloller.

Reduced number of colors by reusing colors from other languages in Braincopter. Also reduced width, so Braincopter needed some rerouting at the end.

[image]

Upper path is Extended Brainloller/Brainloller, lower path is Braincopter.

Comment: What image format does this use? And whereish in the code are the new pixels added?

Comment: @SnoringFrog Polyglot is in XPM format. It should be converted to PNG with ImageMagick as usual: `convert polyglot.xpm polyglot.png`. The new pixels are in the first 3 columns and have colors tagged H, I, J, K. Can be found in C++ block.

Comment: How long did it take you, just to test your answer in all codes?

Comment: About 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

## 144. SNUSP(Snuspi), 6229 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\D v'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(  >77*,68*,@'1   #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz (coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111xx4O6O@ 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #s""oLz
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1 "
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _     @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002086 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6359 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille,
**139** in Core SNUSP,
**140** in Gaot++,
**141** in Floater,
**142** in BitChanger,
**143** in Beatnik,
**144** in SNUSP(snuspi)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZkvayn5cfxoShSokSRNEk99/FFBjNIJ@nGTE86HaST7tx7Mz2YANMfgh4M0I0OMMD01/4V52swmPsP7qwqUi9b9t4niWyRxapVq1atWrVqVdViqccZw9/97gh/UE2VlwNZNZEpGCbq69JM0P0otUSfOckIB4IUhaGS@mA6ERTTOKWOEIuQpPBSH56RqY4FRVoJOsQHENJ0daBzE2QOORMJBs9pgoHUqalNTaSKh7MFEcpO1JHkwzknkjIAMFPQNV0wSXoIoZYic5Nen3uREn5RoKZDuoEygvzj5EcT8epkwil9AyAjCGWqqWwp@QJDFKGyqhsCxsMLhqHiyBhCi6zAvwCNAyinS2opWbl8kcQy6BJI5zRZWCCuZ5g6x5uSquAkFjUqrUZtLwdhaU1X@1MeV9ccCpCMWSRKsmBQPFTlAml2w/hxAB0hXeD6FhglqjrCWdBkLCMJ8ZqGejI39PNIlgA2x8SQgDmKVpAuDw200CaAwVAnwi4dBlIEoY8MTeAlUeJJ6UhYmIJiAPGGH0n8GM0lWUZ9QYYMW5J4LyBDU2MnyiLAT/VVCsGH115UYPN0LACMIqyZIGjAVMwEFbcBcGTNi7nOaRoQCUxsAOGmNAFRkkyngQTOkLCwQhZDUPqEf9pGjFXEKbu1RDOJQxzQO9UJbkPQcdv4CV40FHQBUHIbQXLNdckEFmD2JlFN4HTU1AXBvS/Se0VCYSouwcQV8ZPmOz93Zqs5JzSjlcPPaSZ1pAeb10WKQ/4EOn48g2/C4TijspUM@nJ8j8OWBENTa7qLc6PEL5FB398L8F2wPXqgP1OAlQKuyIhWNZPmfBoQ6DOBQJrDQRzyzQJ@Td4pGJ2/aIsd4bKg@tAaqKCgtpfUjJ/qOu6lW6ZyY6i0rCoD4CdUVp8qmB8KijDQBLwKncyLhBlwTVWsNlLnhMPNoQSNZuAm2ekXlq4hDAVtA7Jnc3RdrqHKUwIHOQ0TCyBwBbJijAURtZHISTLOAukYlUW1LhhT2cR5pkoftzzoEqHvR2syeLWPgSbqDIrjACmJgL402emBhCgAhoZQSVVx0k//8i/7gwHgSfK8qvdtcW2jvsoTrcgRYkHVICywqsLJhCyA8@LSrexQwIyTpT5n4uKVpV0EIYKUOlench@pUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITcUqReNOHGlt6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTartQ5/T0Eq8QB0RmfFNpqYYQz4ti5wG/b3r06nr08d7AYhz@90nxzQ9OAOB85@QKHhyvic57eSeojNMzlClPqUtzaGqBJCPRw4@oWqC4nLu4XB6nXrP6fZjfeZyn0kJ3i9KSt/lBBlPQblO9xmf4O@k04ezF7l3SwQsc4wF91bBxbsdFGgc0idm9ISTFL@2RG2fHdpJU41HzHGc7N@Jxnx5GTezIo7IOILFUsXyAWrIb8iCoLkYP@vGWgLDHaw2TjhU0Rc47AqfSg8e55HTs1t1ggFquldR3Febkoq1lqwNp6CjgSmKoYH21rHo8hwIj4GVuAmDuRf1iFgTzQ@KhajEueDUBdQDPboWI9IjrR6H8/uwnrQxbHvQGm6/Qwv9nf4MugC6tGm8UsqyOoeCCW14@AINouDCuQE0EWS2KpS0KmSVSGL2qzZWQK9gbD0BxXw9CfoC7nWg2m3R36kjgAcDFgxgs/rKjgqacEvAwltD4rbfIEmELjUBLaEvES9g1QM6SLDGFVzIlHRDA8wYbNAwvkA4vN/VXvU0U6eTvlvQ1Sv63Q6FK7/bp7C@QaIwRzKnDKbcAFtSCmTheF7QTFtfQU0MEzTSy2GHRPrsMdRvDKnjzy/LJmOJPbrulIF1vdV69ojIYSVj21I@GXQq4mxrEPUlHbSTvHxZOgDMXhTu@AGD7BHwg@MNEtaGAAiZsBD4qQnKDQR5PpT4Icgupk6x1KM1Fr0sHqJ2SwcF7xM3RWNi2IvvApSf3kRhMt5E4cMt@hoPjLEY1cVeBGn83Yj3MXPG5ABidUMijAc7sX6a84PsfQXnRFXUA0iBkRu0GGQ/xWoHMMga2BiE8WttfZHOurEQN00EbQbaA3o@yN/QNDXjFIYLyRxOe36QFLqpLwtmVcHCQpv6UjJVK9yT1R6oZwP6J70ugeanPWnxokIkbtOGI4OagR0mGigBA/jTFKTO5RQNUJwkPo2Bd5IcRIETFNbVAYAEyA@McokGUck5UCqNpcK7HH7SlfzQ6Rxe5MAd1@GGAM614UtanWAthDrEPsAGX0oHzSWCtrJ1P1H93MERbzMGEPPO6fSPVElxfXF@/PjReeq8AA3/8eMnCJ3j0Ccc8kDoEwn5SAjD@XGI5PCSEE69Izlw3IPz@W6NeeF@wM22wKPTStJc3N3pafDBy92x9j2A725QdaDZANqHb4DH6U4kcNDtdlzMoaL@nmjVvm5xtk@koS4oA0pYaKpuoko1k32sJZv5hIOeGjotSz1agfH1cQI9GOYyjgP5YVKyzg7BuqqaCdJgOJ5A5wDInsNRpjqFPg/zD2kimQUy@5EVLNjbRlunpqHcLYKaJJiUPRptZR1PhLZtA/Ug8IXdOZGoq5ONhjMogR@qyHEcdGBbfm@aiod9OzWEU6f2JHUnPorjJ3iC6eepAc8jn2o9biJtwBgGxJNOP0zmqIHHgyHJJHQTaUPGCUo8EfXrvXXkF5Z5xvGbWejOOLKL8VD625k2yFmC3FCmhoYrR3h2YDptw0cwcF/tCfIiEvIJsug3Fys/VheREGXdkK//FsSBvNRidSgDZULf9y3EFwmcTlkUNmEMK8GUBZUkg6w@7DYztekg95TD6sDB/dHJsU0JbE3Jw/avYxcLEWYQkLGK1eU29AjGXngPBUzfX@cUJWNILnugryh6nUJyG5OeSC4HAE5tmwq6BJ7gY5YU8fQQm3WqihRhTsDI6ECQAaskhaPr5IbHiUP07I94e8T0BHEKU0a6Jyk4/BUwXzxGIMVeT3oLFPiCSV/fD4Dp094htoFwDV8ZRWiP8eZUN2Whb9//2@/3oQFeN8@QW8JUhx9vAo/AN9xUPvHN1rKz4gdyOdyyBGY0lSWOsIGEvoaS5/B0lJM3gcOosUpGPt@Q06Fxl@vGBeHEFxhe35Ezi3JdkKd9YX0/XAhh8b7pZeVWpAmpEdyxHUnG0TeyvzAcrfx4Oq/LKtcnWKxlFknYtrbVLsKCG0Dl6B2NBBryG@hc23dou64Chow5ta54KeVr7Spp@HuYK6f7QsaEuR4rwDSU60lv8BGTEXlLsq0Og00PnyhzYyv4iIOHK2tVR5cGAzC57PtbYGBfwxRI43iBnpPbO2KxHgwQGei593DqsnV9C2S9KLwJvAUIVZXJ5ecIHxEHHnoIlh28oOnbYZP0grEy11tiE23486UIF0hGWVAyCd7jYYJ4wN3MgLdLp5r2dn5sIZD88fjh3NYqK0HAq6IoCF/ruTD6SBNO9gX6O8E3FfHapN2GDoCOuBkHxq7MGSAkps1mYQbNQi7vCS4eUHgsLtvQO2K7JWe90PHWXHmbR5N4VZYMjTT3@uEtjfhylrFFg9fRyWWbFT@95m8fDHs8WPs2ocOdWuVNPF99Q46@QUlZU0U8Gd8RDL/6Fu94dY6/b5oJQ3UmWNfDA9fqIFXfoIJ8MpEMmCy@zt7nvyaueOGTXA5zcXyQKpOXD8aforKq6kNBMVDAz2AzRyGr9TBsy7I1d20Wqm/LtCHJqoEa5PoeL2BCYBjW9bA077JN4hQfP7T62CZ8ONtBosggh5Lk@kbjcvJAlSOxAc3B5U0JmOoi1vT2/Vs13EZDsexXNdTG6FEV1r6/qdrH8P814SDrsDpentgJvmNLHVJn9rT27QrCvACvOR6uXI6JkZx@2prFvdUAOj@cc8v1/R8werzF3fXooS2JyQw2Hc4Qj0HA1C0z@h9SWuj90vrfpqNeoY1@rRI7jTuWBdDY5PqqSVGAYX9mDpZhvl1jifJUmAoHNUi1NxJAbN7THd9OFGNX49he96CBeXiLdgO1sieE30Q1Hs/x07sKh5Ml6ORftWYOqhoN7GwNT6BrEKjhwOuMA2Wq7TXuDu/qU6X@PueG2rpnq/09InHKz9VIsa/bTHumuCGQ71tme3aiwrRXnYANoXxD@9tIyRKRdd1DTGK2mEcSXq3S38V7ijbrmGC/gj0CrSqNDR9e8vo2xRN4a75OgONxmJEpgrnE17e4fUiR9lRV/jmtA/q0L2EzDYxP7KvwtVZ6ZfvYS9pouzJh4FWOnvjWmoQ11tiTR@Aenii/2dA1qJJJBodvaeVXa4DvjFo7K4Jfm0PCiE0WfgydX4fforeOOzfrj/mj7xK8XhWj14H3kMX9wW@xj7S10UsWXPEirbUsu3W2OHqhf7QlcErq@wx@KEwE8viOxc/1R1NjfXsTaKHi74FkP02WTN/Ip0nQ4RV83VsC3jGJTFURDNrk9IGA5yqywIE1asW@pWTXK7EHmVuYcAMh91XJ2i474M1OXpf2gocXIE6t/Qcesn1FjVjTQFUZC0tjfT9sLC95aM/p5F1shzo5j1c3v9qr/fTB1eev2HzKUB0qQ2Gok56xeXqrb4BEmpYb1nuVAPqHnDHGu7u2QtLMEvI9oZ3Z3tDY5bOsyvK38BmrRktRqurhJdgs9q/qQ9afhXfJ9SDBvn11tQ5GcMIuMpS/1YuGwhQGKkM1VU3wkae3QGW81mNdD68qF6pOA3UkQe/jmmCpnEDRUk8W0FwCEkbG7j7B4XWknqxy2JXgHVseOLO@f8vKFK/qh226S041wUx9f@zNEXq@NkKnJBNv@w@@ArjXPD2BMxVpTNs93X48LNH7epdUTUK@DI72yxIwQ1/6cSsndtMb@FZ4gc3eFKkTz63N5r7htV3OIE7SbQcjY@PFd1RQeF0gW/3rrV90hB0QppOpzJmq7kcEzuXiPB63m7Iy4en/QAGwNRTxo8LOFZaLloFkyTAJrCSiuzt0/GVxypyyzyiBHKcO9PBgYSXb/NmFRhyg6lbWu2PuIXHs9Pmcx8575RQxTgIqyDAbOwjK7cGJErlZdG6rjhRuQvw5cHhd0zPLacQYEr8saOU@yF0LzAmydKTqluuD5V/TxHsG//Vv@ra7GowfBppIBljfAwW7WKoTYajOP1nl2qUnNY3D7m4Yx3yIF8Vx6b50EhnQa2C8JF5q6hy1cs2Y7fRiO4HCQw2PGjtUWI2KLRnsimVajWZR01cFSzbtgje51pXiVXk6UaCv9s2h4UcN6MECcarZbINCCIMppo4VVt@LCqgv4NXaPiaMjNayqo7J/i6m5L/@jeXqA4kSFiEcXhdPPP12SkTYAiH@NTyvToHqNZKVoKs2iAszGUaMKTaEoWcJVrwb8UOO@CCBJPrWHji4GMsLJ51sIF8WObGnKt7XP5NE13Gyftm@Yx4Sv0QTWvhvv0@7v9h8c/zCF40YDi9ag5w9Y7naTQ5D8jbViRzHC4ddLewTSVwAN0Jl@z27cJg019qjZkLcKYncCXPiUUM2qhU8IGI/RcWA/gGPboLa6jSJY9fUsrp8DROFsTsvGDIchCwHTOKZhr1DcJbjBfoRDbGs@HjEhhl4shgiY4ekSSK13nEL7m6K0hmhNyUbBLOAPxBMkOocPybOL0hIF/oq9g@8@/5@EWB894to9oE21sy5v1/8ggncAPdUGAaOv6NxB8pWMl@O/RfMjz8a3BI5HM/OM2uTGHr58ZdaoZZtNJPNVgO4@WxV9iin6hNuqymwLGgyx0P3kYnjJbBFlwTj69pjo0E2TwDucqFjDp1jj223e5OwAbVZ7fA5jq3gBgQso93cX8l@KL8h7KS/BrA1kyghW4uiGhEkW2acxq4G9a5lC7cL7u5T0NlrjuAt@wOqkPDIgRLAJR9w6Rt5hF7X0mrBTyQCmvHrjHofxyEUwKstxGsAzKRNWbi@VrpVuYOVf/4nqLEG49o/tsYEx7s1xhDv1RgAt9lIjlyyUGrVs/uZQJy2XvZgc@r43QmR9C3LX9eSLtX2DV1rJmKuGbYP2Ea3GmgmGcScw/Im4pEB5kakO5J9QgNrF4QVmR8lZQM0eb8Pqqm3NLFmA5XuJ74hloOIT0GOI2CWfzPQepGDwrBG4rWPIGiuOQ9a7Acr8zGBI5gN6oBP871A//Qv/9LyY743IfxHdliE8L@wwt/TmEGvfTEtGjeswWxpF2rIIHYkrviEW@zUCY9YeESUlKmApAlwcEYYgsEtYrf13eJx3bWBn9AIwEyserG2JeUJ@oMLe9Kd0jQ2MPAagJ/4FwgLnliYxLHuaYr9ymGAoCPhSIilgUjfbI3QJ1kIfZqF0O0@BVmjZpKW@KHHo/Pzc@QweE4WEpEzi5H0Mfd90PHDhtBjgKUsW@QOQR7Iss0BaRd2Ntcx52HdOCvuck7WiR7OwMyw2gVGKhcJAIgbRys2PxwwFKo2q6DRFWFhEnW@XNtYYOAoxEFKsN4uWCPyASILN3Z/fim7221r7M6zI83@3WZwdDBYA4OdOg6Jzt336N68Vx5sL3gEAvPrA4KkQPiPD7jGb6Qn@dop2/XSpRrXBn1uKCp2ZcgBtcgVoANBmo24d3qKw0YF9OJ@8SOghJ4APYsXpJGqGcl0tlCs1hqvnIoJpPMlmBM5L8499z6/9@5hE3C@kPo1U1M5ulFO5das3KVquxqIIbZLgi/JPFTaS0rfKL1j@Qu8LpskvCqIZb4VMZl0@3Jk1fw19m0qvQOYtvYzX5Xqcn95vns4v7hXjl4V/@Oh9y2O/CdYuCB0b5C3LZzogM4prL0gmvgdOcO/dqsLOLZvE22cCa3nbfTbbsGbN@62vsFrfwvsFxy4oPvCjFamskz53/DEgLr7aaso4hhrEbamF3TNmlQWk7otkKderejuUoPsurx@OdD2j9wwqWpNT8l7D5wCMxNd4i1ogyhoaxJLnPRhGlMwtzMfmE3hVTgywVuSyQyois3ucF8ia1EwmbZrsElpCBPJ11zTgxXH1tcXFBn2YR1C3WAqfsYl7hZo41X4nhuw39BkyXRh/9uFH08SoTYuN64Aey4L2H33PP5g@wqjtUuvh3gF16bAr5qqoe3EPCOsQ3WYm6HMFJCDGAioOJ0AnEhudQGPEgKqqD7IDHx0rom4g1Jcdh38k34YSvcPhUVfGsBI43J7QSX9gmW3/sSc2wMTaifoYYtVl3jbe5cxP8sHeodj3B3nl5S@sHDh911OHzB3IN4578ycbscrGSCO2LZXdv@lR/ZaWXCm3Wu33swvFEI8vlEE@30nHvcPDQp7fcK8AkpsmHoJgjCGusQJpyHXlLi0G8iPyKPr3qV4DVN3I98FHs/mSEEeD5mRwI0k@BHJKZKQJOPVJRd@EcxFJ6Cdcayh9PFtJWnojvX7HyBMCnGjY7ymkAZzA8/G3RQYnJDllKCFARj@TjFFc5h7YYqs@zEplsILAjpAHUwmHXkwJB0QeEFqjS6@Q1ttsO2BFlfj8VO7NfbVYRyBWJwf0BiA9oCaW1ucwF/bdQ@4hpUYQKVhqimBQvl8JSgK9FcXyMwEeifipiBkutu7fjnZu33BjZRwZJGYt30BgdD9F9@yzi@yCvbMMX1G5rVnzzDu/3CPB37RHvqX9O/Rfvrsi@tYTixpMMbcF67jYYL1BE88nmPlxHWsYHPku@/wdPj5GKydR7/D71gAkO9Ydp@BPIN1lDhWzo65c9dxPxE4ITng0eNxf4EMvzRo/5dj7pk@/g6sCS/E6FbvdB0bbtwdGL@ffQb6cA85pr0gM19cDuQgrxbj4o8ljwfT4D9@xAT8kr5veMi4ct@gycz7zDZy6cFkrUb2bZVNS7x6VdpioB19utHoYeLTbW33PK6Bd997O5B2yD763e@O2AhMoj5Fgi71UyD48eQIHX120CcO3fHlPoNmzjtODPifHmrjWu3Gfe8CkXQepasONuT4HqETmjqiT5gfozT9ww8/gPWJ7i78F/4H953P@XDnQugiGj3xRmIn3s9OlkyiYULGsm5XIOCm0X0D3Uc57sQTCnxWziRJ0ox@H77qEI3RCj5jEeF/El71d8IcDvfEFVhyKp72JLA4fYAPW3M6w0Fn43v8tsanj/BH/uGzecTXjyTGjiYgrz8f3cj1tKCOLvij1RHLskdL8veIwyy7OPR53AnTLBu4Vz7g9@kjHz9/ANYIHvI5Pf1M5jvIEY05VJU8oCFgDSP1CEbIhYB6CC18@EMdLZoc/kPNHv6rm/ivPcZ/dR7/pcb4r7QqrQ5SBPT/MpHw/NyP3/@4DlFHP5z/kPhHfEj9gA6YuxxdXDw8P3t8d/7vzzxnZ/iL/6Hfr4Nn5GOFgIgHj89zfnd@7r@4WFz4Hi7uqKMvwJNn6ijgACG9P6GOEovzOqH0LnNh0/xkT8dLED73PdzVSmByN72Bc99RIJdMewONVuqIhafw9hEnBvFjPZvMVFsAXStlk43sZaGdbdUg3nh4vPj82eOHVvns91w8ACmLX3guPAnTNNHt44kfvft5PBCyHqmjzMWiRfvOgdqSHVMn5fju4ene7b94@JE6uju6c30KfAowMjNj2DE7LqvV7X@1CvHSghmpOjNkhmyfiGioGql@RozQYpbMcsFM1Crbh6AAf8wEghIjLpgBozAKy@6he/t/UlXLVRVQqZDNXDAmxsqIcB9Uq2VAJkL5I/iTGIZZAJ0LZgb/jEx6Dfv9I0Nq7Wbu76k75PhBAL3hZ51@xumPOJ3SQziiPX15DkSe7ohVEY4/3AkLyXxwIK/z8f4uHo87H86OaOP@nrZUqSMQcpxhkOfnx8dMspl8fKTxIsvi/Njz2eP7DJ/Ehefcvn066l@cfbo/9WEBt4Tc/3hEn3@6vwj6cDjiAb4HIO6c/tmdZoMS7h/vKadr3ul08Lczn82tEAlYcfedTSq@dGiIskI4Cj4YlD6Ufz@weC1sLtdd@OHLs9vt/nDvPHNajHK5kACmuMvB3i8CIgo43MRGj8MAxwaxGRUJuy8uImF4jsTcPhdDkq0s9w5N0@4dfjLn9xO3pEQiqevckgCFYIy9d3D6473jLvCQSMTDJDrsi0eQqvviQbfD7f6ePT@3ywi4IdrhXDhU3Ym@PO/@ub48n7vIx43/3G4caV8v3C5IdofhafHFtTh3nbtwHEThXF@eL3CQwH2B0J3L/eB@frbi4Opyn1s4L9zAN7yw8U/4rxrI0JDz6PkI20YKCoXdrt5ScIcirpgnbv8lPkIFXI6gMwj1cjg5593d55PgSTR09@nh5OHEdX7iP7m/eNjT327nEYKushbtBHuE@UYd@c/qDjbgcGJRP8M7FKos@GV1gILxs31hcD66Tl5@Ymzcc@L5fHcSj1tln5z8@BF6JaCDwhzwOQL5RS50fnG@EaoNxoX7AmC/IJvJEH7@AnJmJYKp5bL3IO7vFwzp7m501kscfznins8IfvTscJ7tySvB73KekU0qxxfHMaffsQ@OZ8fxl94ztklPWDcxfcKhs7OTkBWOxiDMnritddcwA0/rMKQIBscTxXB2hMXJCTx3Q60SPWEgKWCH7jHJEw6H6QBcF7@IZAML6gxv5lg7Rw6fw@pAKBYn@I6QYcQpmPb0oOXnKMrAoC3jVy5UUfxoxcP8DfUEAUxoQZbxKiSe3oCVL/fnMKX@SB2BHgNLyhDgM6lxwlQQ5tPpXNh80pJxyo2QawTTc/z56dd/8NOv/8effvMnP/3mD376zZ//9ld//gfw/Rv4/ol1/5P/EA/j629/9b/8bz/91W8g8r/A9z/D9z/99lf/5vetL3n@O/j@3ztxf2d/d@CsLwW4/vlvf/Wnf/3bX/2Lv4Dvv7O/f/Hy@9Of/Ufr//@x/3DwNz/92d/hi/3wB39C/f3f/hr//@nf/v1//jX@/9//17//23/99//835PAX1qB//ff/QfrCoX/@R//9G/@EOr0Zzj8zyAM/8jjsz4eG@CPcOSPxwxYlej@x13IH2kWhiBE70T@EfrxHjt9sltIwP9vf6QZFqItyA3OXcg//u2v/tVfQ@yPMJqyrA35h@vstgztQe7RCQX9EUD@1Q7AH/3069//6a//h59@/Zc//fqfU2Abw/9H9JEKIHzHFxxJAiS0OKHCQZDTdZjdhoMhEg7D9ZDlgbdsPn3ei7JwnxwCJoCfSPrHg4YMLuNkTduhwj6u8x/E8Al9hmQYs8iwtcBX/AAxOExUHrmtoxY2IHm2YOznnZxWjPWMdrLvx@PInYzr26FoK4EUuQZCNrKFXSjaorerQa0ps4AXryIoZFePoqKoVYNLvXCZb@7cm9lkOk9FUKpayby4hW2gMCplc83NY9RKXWcNb1B0s6XSy0f71lWniOewciJHOizIoUv@83OWpS4a2SZENKuIDTB@6uIGLfyoVrumsD78iMJRr9fv98MF373kQ@7@4@/XIOzblvCR4XCopRVVxjsKcdZy8JBwPgjpQhxvaYMynSvEo6CHz/aYam9Hwg1H4aAuDYYmMufqBsAwDLChNtbV2rLaWFgd1OM4/P25HyhB2P2Y70eYVhkk7lWK/BqcysOYMsEv2WPXLRPPsCURMZQfj0CBQDwWjsWDgZg3Fo@FwmwkHPayAS8bjUXjjBfm1jE2EgvHWW8sFA@GQqG4FxoyHI9SR4LSl0SahhkT63AgEpAUHr89eo5fw1X9wwvqqC@IkiJ8QAtX3/3hqL@OQNMYcgRj9wxy0LSDjVB4J/JkkQDbG@/RBlnQXg7KwSEeHeVyaSaXczhS@AEUMJNmHI4@fgjHGCaacjgEkpKOBZkAZBrip2yEwb74Dgk/pJO5HMYwwg@BGMbhcIytFOtBXj9EAUzBD8EgRoAcjqcNOgaQqxZFMZLLtB4YJpV2OKYWeTH4A7ik9RQixGbxA07AmXJWShrSHI7LdSYYVxyOugVnF5Vf1zeZdDgK1kMyiVEUSeXDVqWu8EOSfCCTDk8gvg7HAAIDHSwGh6MHQSzEDgcPIX7JQdwEQth3VTE5h2Np1QPXxOFYEGiOHzscj@t4KAfoyee5odkXBtZnqVt3HpIKkCQtptlc7/KyNxj09GUye1knScVinhstp3pv0LMz9h7ho@JckDSeLF9@BJz0@MjJh5OuIEl5kfS4fBQIhY/cE1Bmfwa4oMljEScVIenQaoaNED4TAO7hT2oC9xTXs5LWH5JE7otez3EGUkvh/oOWLvcXMrF0IUNaCaB2XIx3CtOd8KdpzBGJOk5P4O745AhCcOFCjBMMWIfz3uFw38UfPjmiYcep89Mnn/M79hNyROOOU0c06kDuM0cAOl/Y4YigQNThuAWbTxj4nOiT40wXzKmuoMDZM6ZglWDOCCXoyYXvnBdfe@4vNljv7BmvcQOZT66VJ8F60cr9CVMM8zaY6bpPSR3Onmn6HKsGFi@D0NQFzpOwVsUBLubYpFjKY9P7kc8H@hvB1@ejcLqWsPjgcsRdCIxSUYLrvYPY7NZSpcvpjAacTrfzDJB8RI4dfe4@I7Qii6euNWMcwApgTBymmHbtXXEfTICQLw6UvyJJH58aJqfjtWtS4ilyROIOHI0PE4yvC/vs9bHe05Ne@Pziv6MsgzzCUkfPVB@/URqKo7P4GV4egpni@YWd5wotowNPfofkM@rYiYl2BvfmzUfkeoyNuCNfUA2pR8fHx9TRefPCEXRU/Y@b1YALmiwq3V@chRJpPNEHG89//3j@8eevseHM/ovP65WxC7wm@OoTClG6gL2s@vg8QmsiHwtjvg6QcQRozjz/kA@UTCUAKXWG53qOIw06Fy@jJV6TRPdWRc9/eURm@qj2Ze31MlXIxtxpGW/DuLjTBnn3/@4BuX9ZkeQvsaDvgqxjYwlF0NLPjfj30e9j35db1VY195k5jZ3G7u/t5vSyTtZJmspaEvsMI5VUz1JHxo9uNcz@UimeHZ1qzmDICYbvfeLIqjwbdR9dBKJ@g1sePdguo65QFAssPJPZX4BFR2Jn/zPfe5hNyFohFBX7vf5gIAV@r/zDj8c07XSCIX588eUbPs935@fP5/jzbAfw5fn5@fzVP7ltP2/AbNM9/6CVJ//j0UPkl75z6/8cLumqxR1HJOxwYy9g4/vH7x@PEEw/kSMQxj3ZQyNrgrk7HXYtTpTvTxT4E04M8icI5FE5Ob@AKAMi7GcBQwjuE5qmrwNgncTjkVjkiPodTb@3gw6pmy0lURB0Yzo5tKeU1KUyh/fblM2@EgTK05Wgw319wOHajEHYjsGbptiQ2Y2zbZudKHIu6H7c0qCx3x6OpSgcksh5s0jE6tGFF1hM4n@FTvCprNg92U19oT4ArilvEpc/uJxR1Afse4YfXWs4L/rOMN3YL4dxUx8@2HreMP2G@YiR40x2pI89o54pzB6u3zcQ3u4jbjaWTzOHPblUzXpxS14iK5NBBjLLIiPuyLjcHYJPkGhRAbU5QaREQjmunFX8BwusNxUxKblCKQt5UAKJZNvYzu3Qe/j8LVK9j6LbLhwxEIWxYHDCKQKOAQEdRLoIbvcEO07zLgLpQSxOF8n2M0CBheollHiRaGe8w48PkB2jF3lZNQCxVbrLqgE6ebSLteuwHj5xJYCFuHZkbCJjrD7gvXbr4QNN7h7c6MvaPdOFU9E5Cmz9R21c0BjW0bkkIz/pW4JDDjaz2UywsQ9eaNozy83PtYGzY7aMeqZOTO/kzGoq7Yy6cvHuL3h78uyXk@@@47/X7iYPZ@5JwsR3j2cCQ@XYJVkgJ2ZikgDx0O6khzPzzuORHhIT95ULP8MoDEbFMyVazDbcdt2g5koCaMEuDIbbu7pTfL9UHry5O8UDJE@9J7eJlZdLMN4FfCUwNWTvU4K16wFlmomVRznjzuGLd0r3XCjBbPBwZ3tROMvYJSdWd9xDAvghQ0aPJweVATqNO9njeXBD4TIkvs54Jn/3HeeRLxZnss/nxlDfBz/l7kwIPHgS@PnUxZ0vPq3uppD/1AX3BBQju4F4yGfz@nlDO9B3Bjy22nRLukXjApO3APImicTJ7aeT25PEx4@ru4Vv8uC12H/KbKUBE7/AxJ/tuKi6Tm7d6AVLyKKny/EL6fQX/hMDObySxwNM9mo7OS0KT24hRYOx26b6GetLcqLnehceS5jtVmkdgEaOSiKr6uTgUYMctmz2sYM55E0avCTZ4NabAZoEs2IOHxHqRYqq@DgCgdPsE4Zx4v3i0ydqXbTt8wclY@XSExCHZ9fkgEkdr8CS06qtd2S@pl8PqeG1zt3MKRuF2yyC@WswstNdiWoiHc7Q@TsMgtXAF@b5zNJYlqcnKBuiPQCGaA8M58NaBDPJ1hM2ZMJOhNZaNxDkwnpCtN4RwidtGVg/gXrb9nxQIRYZ0JkPkCF5Rwmim0CeJAgh6ZyUBwHoKtQHqASmAddBekAXoMjQd98h@/E8AXPyKB4LMBiGG3lYDPSKUij8GygFHJjKEcgo1oekEKDtA07B/sl7BYX@cQXZrxe4IINn5LXeMvCTtwxcU8WwXq7BfHNbZOC2@PBh5EmEbILgn0wVID@kPf/uyB7uT1G6Wq61mtl6OdmAK8x1YttDjE83x92@OuRSw4dX9iSFeOPyXJ0VukUeTBgwXE18FhI@zLqPiq0SCgQqGS8@uQBYf2StfcGAerrBJBjkVDjDr@oDei6NJXr/FHx88DBx/CVn7vvWpxBjcsjgLG9f@dm@8WPglS0YzO3XrffOQZ8IhmGf3elbH4dOjnwnLz9N8Ds80Avtsz6JT9XaLYQ4IeHNBy9xbdOlgUTOuB5aCPbyk2MZTSs76R8UPqOzz5kclmgqHmOYU8R4cYBdBwLrQHAdCK0D4XUgsg5E14HYOhC3A@waM2thholpMBjZBqPbYGwbjG@CIWYb3GIIBbbB4DYY2gbD2@C2tNCmtEiM4EVHa26SrivoOI0NxdZp@L1BxSSRYUDDvowMAaGBV5CQPfQqEsqL7UdG44xdUIGuYqBAILJ9Bu2zhk24LKq8Fh1eq2TryY6EsYqyJmpEYLO6Dlopu8CHEoPQuU8RfoWBokDtIl4WODAGBBOslEQO5F9wn1qv9unL0@1rDBhDgt08Q3Z8aCfkYcn52pb4HEgOHEq2sAUOYrNe0EQbxuy8A2ITaVF5ujfSWhhDe3G7WD9iBYs5@gZEwILAbbD/0si6zKY@PVhk8P0i9xAeLPIVURbe8KFcmDcugjyxzkrGf4ItsS7PslME0tpgBtg/pkBk4EWD4nc8E1/YU8dvf/UX/wf67a/@9Dfop7/6zf/3n/5nHP6P@PJ/gs2CAhuAP/lTfPm3@PKv8eWv8OXPdjIR@OCp46e/@DU8/k//Hv30B39qJf2rv3Z4QxtEkIKjtjn//J/hyx/iy//l8IY3gH/@xxYgzuLwPlN7ppULoP7kvyAEpWEsG2R/8TcIOTxgYLhsybuz@vjDzhthFoING@5I6OFlunXlhzpmO@P2OACv/cRunzy4Adw7yHUO/zrAtu@BOWN5ImMtzXP8EL/1Y0epBrZ/eGzCqIZ/API274PRY69tOKH2/z06RU4PhoFo8mprwtLhdv3teju2qRjW46CBOnzgro0Kh90bSmB6S4F8k5nA0vDjaQuZkbKWjNj8reBfH1kPII61ZEmmi3VTdlnr3DDpQfYh7vC/nepiocXDkPVqKPkxBcp@gYXdKXBP3bxoNijlZQxMGbcvi@1mJRHCRIMmgWwbfmPG4gfCBe9LdNuWs7tNtpp70WHwpwcm5nhXI20KSiCH4yuwmNM2vBtbXMF9eIteG@COOQ0@7L16dgjYcXNz46B24hgsQ3rfRTDsVMpSGZskdj8psJMU2EkCmi2cRNeEA4EXNJCBA@vF/dcsrWw7Kmo/21a4cM9ZtwMmA@aC1pqmV5SnxjDxGjXRyPvK7jXyHZTsQ8LuJ/cK0TkXyOF@lQFw7udJvGzLw6iZVzCvG@pwTsztvZi91nob016enU5BuEe95NKm5dj4oZbbL/Ad1OyD5xsLCjD/yIJ831hQJPz1gl42K867h/5t/n5d7azVxEbDb5FZHf9ob4DCQ@NfgOht1RGmWCdBlxumPEl7ytObq8h14LR@iKfXRxXtHdGv7xxghCcxFdUUrOWBz5oKUw4VW8E7P/Fz6Ge67F/UGSiqLhi7r5RK1us5ihO/1MyrAwVGNS8@Mkmyf38C77VbZ2jsjyubkc22QtPWrwZh1BajsOX5@Cgpkvn4CManLLq3DMSPfh6/M@Gk8M8NQWgnv2tj2lY1l4qPfjPdX8dJ7F0rW1Pix66qZic6oZAkggkdL8gw@UJDjh/jH84iLMFVJC94You0Z7rcmIlDdaIOBEXF73Pj3C/QF7a4MUGcphFavIjzIn6HInsS7eK9nNvOevWzs6KrgItzb/IH9hHsMcOL9Jc8xpzVDxT3@GZxVrZ1eY2fT29jl97G@/SKkm6YL2kmkXi1B99/XtFB1xYDAG7JCH6dDK99hMMrcvZI2UTjX8GwMnwziX3B4GH4w5QmATRpg/tFkA/v5smApw3h7bf4/34DrrNnv7X5iDHbWIK@mWSx7UemaAY5RUfhBReAF9xY97wubiPamW8sy57okBmeFzmI4lLwqzfQMTVNUIzNXvMa8VdkHjsBvZJ74hmUsBIP0KTPvGgceLuJMo99QeaWQt9lQ3p38K5rXBe4PtFX31ZxrOiI0lOtnz5xMV52zxQjr0gSoNM3RIbzztzut8XKApE20kM24wiFhbf5RxbuXqpmvAiasPZAVB006BE5G4WcSKMttaX1WrVs/eKarUet8cdqyQp@2/yrDAE@WL@nxXq3xbrfU59116ZK3zAibGD9@1XGb06uMeJ3F1@34c9j0ddrSlYZNpkS61bes07eanHpvRbfkYq1TFpWybeJ5NeE7ptlbkfULGRbFZb@eUPIK8xpTpZ53rWL0Yp5t8VU5ZVOwHG4xVTljVHl8YBC3eQkms7ER9cnLPvCTUkQLMB9Bvc23DFCmIM@WgK1rhu2a9dLXiRlwmk7Vosdc8djW3SHi@7dfcQdKGodxgu5z5sy@TfL5F@Vye@VuekB@0XuAFH8XpF2K@Dmea8JZEE039DOOAnP3OH2ntqGj6JyOt57/eKUnKeSFzlnzlNQyE7BeZp1gVJ29p2nGRIwnKcNEhg7T68gsO1bzh@dp@tugQF0eCSBzzjeVuH4mXeepl3uZ4r8zua6XL/zdNOmAPPJeiQcebaWV3v2rr@6WVUVBK9lVHoRlhgDbiqu1t2Dl3wZ@Ceg9oFjkPgxgQInBBhPQPYGjZ0RwyoHhg0/@SE/16Hh43S9NGWvb2zXUCDdk9hZVMFSMiX6yHnk3FdGFmE4lSw@wh0IxHrz9DBFiH01M/saOXbpIKGkkffLJ9zzE3ug7yLpdwC8u4gjb/Ov22sfhdWA30YnzvwWna/IWRdHKMLOAO4DZGGm/uB8p1K4rV8cXmW1/m4LvV4jwI3oW4NYrUTQ7uh0sOGwbUoK01RtX0hIKt7tk3bz4I/dKbH0vshGtILdM99IJtF2zbBi2O387veqs5MPk7angnDiHfNg9bLNuEB0MU7a6rodS9XqfEDCjs7pk3MnBCy2GTtI4Cx14yVjxVvD0DqvVSTRXPtqEjL78etyU860St/uy@CX6H7e9HWdE0xwoBEj2Mm5KcXSr@rPsN9Vy35fG9RrJrwo4JBhfXgofW1evzvKvqBc3hb7ugFxohdl3AeNo00JW5bD7GDHMn9P1l6Z@PgXjSwj3yp0g/2Ftb9m22ZO8BW@vZxbWLiwlaDP9iPHeGF2HHibUa8tEnnmXxstflySjceq@IbSbdXep9Wq@KEmxil4jIbbz25gfb@BdxsP4yMV0F@w3Orl@JchyT7Fpm/jNfWdnQtr10HFXmKbo9h2IkHdE/@1jYsWRFQf65lqpdSFQTcajbpfb0XgXgt5t@M49e42wWbaEvDic3fI71Vj34mhqpsf7xXHa5cyEgHGAEf2bSzxs/u429ZlO/r8Rd@FfBbsDkdtXONtN@D2tBI2dTg8ZEs2X63TtF0nnI1kbd4Cv71ktoZ3jbB04A2dx0cyfD0@Yuecx0d7FMNNs9lG@t2R/YNagZ0fnT7a92YiFpfx6nALvAAwnVg/eWwvwNnHVlh@KEf458XNde5NrqliSmtnB7w@hLeoNp4RriDrtn6VfB1j/Xg4SKorEMJT2EAYv31s5cLQeOGTuFba5Xy0DB18JquhqYr96@Jj6xfoyQmxxnrplZA9VeYccQOxSiEvTe9QZDlkrffFyA8Gk/PLrV9n5hRrCXnNGy8SBn6y4xOIw5RjLGnWsWwb1w/DTTIRgomPFvC4JwsT/KO9ILsHVpPLErTKMCcNBiBItH1EvOXg0sS/4@tTRV96fdzIEWqTn162j7O0fcLIUbL2OjCw07V3XoyBAhGwpuJe4Oz2C4zFbjIInwnDECctAgXfKNyiVjDm3cn70bV079/Z9ceN8X10PeKWtd62lHR8HPyMU3b4bL@EubM0bW9aEj2ws3O5PvqIso@qSpB9Sj/2UdNcjiPH@kAoHLTcJjiZX5@k4sJn@JxSHxSieLAHGOIt3xowcBVstJHtNffGJVVBv0DBAPl9SyiPWKmkWMBh7eztYYc0yIqJtbz7bAXj@EXf8Qu8mUh9OMK60JI1nH8tyjhMDrbcyjL6aKOzNlRwV7a6wPohvPMQhKnGhwMFf3Q5PIDF43A79jABvL378cHSvK@zglJ0/45u9iOdnJpMJpsTVq9fJgfJYbLehecUU/J0RqEsTWfzcj@ZKfSWl2q0ORMDTLN7neoFPbVof6FJ@Uk6r2UpKdSdeG6Di3g@tAqng@kkz9yIlyUxFE3fiDeGkJSFOD0bja/7Ql3rsbohXVXKlfqKzrWu24PrkXjb6YyiSoPS6repwfVCuI51lFm7FS8Y10I7XTHHlZE5ZZfVaCfSmitGqt1MDYvLwny8KETUrhROXwvRtqjl5/wyrPH5FnU7aw4jjfxyHGcn/WUybfS7UY@H7qZTg1ie79@KxUb6qj/Qw73wuBHngrNJUdSWw6u88lQapRsz3qONcoXIjFJqhdlcCHXGPTmv3Nbb7V4mVZuPWeNW649CnfLU7MX0SDA4TQrDUShcmJp6rJRKXkXNTLLQzsk3bfN22Y7VKDNvNqOtIh@XPbOqyQenmRZtMO1FUbpqzCP5QFPNK0W5MKqNL6eXNVmbjjMhqdqchPTBTa6nBgL568Ys3y1ReqjY6cbqo0Aswy94@iqsqpNgM14p6eXFNPVUFTppvpESehEmFb7JsqNydclXZ6V6vVPTOq1J1Lhi5dscM6KqN3wjmRrnSpMY26wsC7HLQmOaThcWs15AHKjJab8TLN9E5qWKUOhc08E8NzXLHildlelRsWgs262rwk3FuIVuXS5KIXG5SLVTuviUSRvleomu6ONhIzRS@lo7KqVVvlgrhMzCOJmfd27jhdRYEGu9sTpuduTO1JQyIzpHLdPj61ZPmOek1ZzLhkrta3qUrfNmNDkINuiRKPbGctVYDS5Lq0Fj2hv049VLJiM8XfVT7XA9q7HlnBGqKEuq20yJ0qp@LbLjWjxfuO1lk1JZCadrgla7zM8WgUBXEmvz8Ipd3IxyIWnBh5hSNXVT9lwXA3VPyZNK1dRgdUAFMrnLziB85VFzwoouidxTNO3Rp9PQIjPFP9NcaimyPgnLTCzX9Ayjht6Jl8vznlG4qac7vLyK3ZbH48htnbqZFQxVD8SKuWScro0Z/ZIbVQq3UUnJheapSzkbL3RWrZiZLU3lWL40yBTreqY54W/i2UFjuRwPYkWhVhonKSGWqddHvUG7t@g2jNqSKYf4Uc@TvcxWngbQj9uNXKDYSkUG03qwfZVRZrVmzrNSbzolLV0Zs9labBppRoMTarYoxpINU5G0zGU5HrmeSqVsMjNopVlVEG6e@Ct2zDWaSyZmRPXr3M21ZnjMZk8N9Yap4PK63KXbt4YRzkvU7aITKSTHOn/VX5hFI9pUAmr1mmGvxUpLDs860lO3po6SE/qqdbOie/NVblEzebMxVsP9aHh8uTCe9NWVfkXFuiNOblXSamnER6660ipKh1ml2U2LZb5bDDDJ1iBfFnL52WDVEiaBUf5pmuc53qglu71LOTJbaB4xGJuVqGalczOIPj0xPaHSjUvJcateK5iBJkdPu41S@KnUNYwc3ypIqZCkTDOp7uV4kr5dck1jsZo2Iz1ZXNb0AJOlFpVuuc2P1IGRM2750eomd6uUp4HITXUkRs3@mJ1IbKktMtGKVvdkPDX5sjdYRtpTYcaDZahdFzQ2lRyNqlSVnURnqWXcMJVL46rSSxeTUjJZigWutUA0P05f5hd9qd1qV/J9Tg3d9tLBSLU3YAL9VCU7qIUmg2itEg2V0lSzt7yus/1MTGKHnJweFZchLV4KpCJ0e17PX4@aQ6Uip5OdhZgK8k11Hu1wotISVpEoXWY8o2G8qCSZUC1CtcyM2Srl5kGPclUoB2rLJX/T46ZBTnzqGh6@uxquqm2BU@Vh6anONtvTUloajdqRFN9kqqkGM10Zc04r1ah4pqawmdJilpsPGx3G0DJ5LdZbVPrpWk3oaf2gJvaqyYXIzDqd2@vrVlWZ3FxP8vVor7rqc6Nw2xTrkerCpJ7A5GnPSq1cb5ERDXFUnz0pl4vpTZsOtS4npVZ/5hnFb7uzoHRTZUqVVFvkpoXrQdRsVRZauSiLMj0JVAc0NW/VVitTSKrZyrzcXYjt1SoppYwndnFFc6XLQubG9MSzuWSm2mxwulytXpYySW4yL89LN1GPsGqU@2Fp/HRL1RRFDui3DTmaYoJGoBXOrNL86JKZXqYmzWIzzmpsK98ul6/YocxP@Gi3mol0ynwnmSxeLYsi167VtNpVq0lVPcrN7W2TrjblUlwsFepNNVyY6eVOJ8rN1eQ1xxRCk968tEjNy9NpZxIverqmwAXVlSCw9blcooU8yE6MEqazWrpSM5aBp9XoaTDLqDfteFK7jCTTS7E/E2YrJpmZeWgjt5j3I5IWCzS7i0uxy5cHg6t6ahjUZlozkg5TxbhYVtq99LAcXwpX@VI7NzWFRr8XkjwGo42a18mW0eKX0iUfGc5aRleGzidq4WYqHTfk20zsSpc8TIxPUXynzNXo0jB8Uyn21Xl6UW4vMzDliLFijQmrS6U9jY2V/JWRuuo8XcVig1YvP4aCp8PbIS@1PKl@T7gW5Qp1e3PVHmdr0zY9ur4pR2utvCe2CuqXT7w6vOTiy@aqyjCCGB/MCtNFUCvxscvYVZWXi4tKvSUKg0gjcC1fKisqo0SHTFJk57O5QnuW4VQsOxBTrYqiZ1p8PiqoNY6mF51bs9q5iV0FLplrpjGZMwGjPKcZsatIy26l2w30qdTMuNI6DXaW9eTNZLcxqvOXMl3p1AsrdVnKBoxWspIWr6bzpVZaSnrwli9dpuUaL7FgloQjg6beGq9Ssx7VEReldCoWvQ3kQYIMQ47PuyFO4A1tsBjRpfI0Ly9G03Fb90wWdN1z212E48P20KD5UqlZKcyzelgtGiOFikT4QL6ja1Gj/jRZFtJmZthuyaF0vD3oVfNdutwUr@LX6cZtVAjX6MKTEO80IgxfCnd4mq2rk5kJIxI/GFOlJdPXeVnQuei0@hTOTqee/nI2NT3abfTyKtYZjNPsjOc8wWRPfeIW7aLMSJWoMDCqnfnsJtcBC1Fpz1oKlbttacErKS828u1qeczWkvWVSafiHf4mNOjqrKiIs3rQDBcLwiDKi5ns7XiUyReeCkxXfGLmrKxfXwdzeZaKip6UqfZlun2tXSurACcku9VYed5fpSfDiijkC4GM3q1H@o0rTs7CMCo9lRitnbss3fZ78pAWVaXaqDMMdRsJZDs39Sd21r@urZrqIq8PismaHLwRC4pau2mzmWudrkRTuev0qH6bXsYiNV3uCc1BrKlMPJdBleeSSilCRYWZkGp36JYgBdnoYtXjxgLN3nbG41ieXkWMFZ1UjPkoNljFe5cTtnNbUS@byzF9OVnc1lI37FTwsGyN16hrc1ULX152PFfLy1ZhILcKIk9zk@XIyKemQnHeu44kPTGNaXqy/fZwUaoNtE6WjvZ6MbYRDHZC5lO/tjSuK1Q7U8oHo5mluRCz42llEctryUhjuWhdh0Lj29GiGmtE6uEFO1PH2ZSWG4Rp9caIKotmfpBLCVmxLBrlVY@fUJHVtFLIxbKesMB1a91bRszST42@bA4HYvPqJtiI0Hw4X63Nb28zSXoSFUfZgnwJY@KcKy@WjVF33LuuGkGJUqtdTyGyiqwat9eVvlLrFMvD3nwQjdb0fHsUn666Wl2qe7RVq9BTLzO1iZxZ3YDARerx8KglZ1sd6SZTZ6qUGekk52CDs6mStBzQhTBzJSpMcTG5jN9MOpFxd9xOz@rdxXgUaUTD6lRYRc3OU3gqtKLd4qRB873ufOgJXFJqY7W8yV6H9FJlrpXMmipcMbFA6XbcmmSnLc8kfZXrmekOo/UCndJ86kmHwSqIldvxQKV3NUoVxpfXRv46EKeaOWk5jY0uI5eeGgwm05FRjbXlgDyjO7Tcns@E8YThKhmurS96rVypX@kHYrTmkaJz8yryVOzWbjlTCyk0ZSwj/TnnyWfBgshI3XDD0zY1ZgJzEeZmFrxSBsGAodw0GryZVqPjVjAuhHJ6W1HbC3XUDkjXl9HxnJeuRlRKWPVDcqve6VcWq3k/Pg71ucaslczdKJ1gWtGGC0NnI/GrQJt7qk30YNXUaqUWn1KuJxwnzj0LOZUp640Z1R9Ukv1O7mkqztqhajKUXN70mdD0djZildVNthsY1XrJoTivd0Kr@jyY6l@ySn0iaRM9QDPNtpIdxxatvHBFFVdZYTmMXadq7VDrahQfB@XBuFFjluOqJPK3t8aULXQHpWu2Xwi3U9fxcV40kkK0FReLI3pR6VVvI@m@EGIoz7AwoQPpEh8sZm88ZpGXw0/Siq2Yq7ioLCstqdcYzJJaqT9qTSupPJ1iA7PLRXUSzNfp4JRLTWKZK72ry5SQDScXrWo5Ygxvk2Y7pNYCs5h2W5MGN4F@bcjxEyYSAx1c7vdul61kPTUvdSv5hpFUBivBo8@vlMtCLpdSqLzYqTwZT5wqTpOhVrXUvX66TuqDZrhnGgV28STQy6VSLaZ5ftlNFoxxpV1sKIUoM@mnytHrYb@ktNSaFLyi@Hh0fBOllQZfnDJCqJYM5Z7al/xTYRapq2PF5JvZW9as1EHZFcKtqtadT1bpISMugqHsjVEd9LVb6K2jFRWY5uvdfl0cKYt5vWi2r4KTBjtuz@VxROE0Tygbr1Y5dhDEk7DwjapMVPlqYN40KrMrnaaHq8hU0C6FK4kqBbRBslCPFAPc5WU3E2@xk6eSEIiVQ9PkPFCtlz1KWNAyhcFEZtLj@ki4lmDK0InURkWmUZFag9tp@ia@bFCrbk@MK8XOXL1Kj@eZ8WzUbC2CML1qtkuG0ajfmP3CLNArRuVeddhvZnLpaz7NcUa0qqSz1bE2bfcm83woTI1ywZtROVqUBpFxtCAsu1dTLV4rrgrpYT7k6SrFmNnlTPmpKo@eKj3T7D1FpXbjukh3UlFeYZ6WUfNm2KENKh@bZC9DQnRVGLLRljKZTaf9al1RC8vadRnYHA0Em5c9Oql1rmtmu58X@Jt8Cyz9oioUGjdFrXF5k@9P@wolB0F807R@dVkycjeZ8S07L9SXPYn1jKtX82o4GhbjPc8sPKkMp5lwuBOdFCuzXEbTI4syaP1BbVkrCfVKmWIn5W527CmKLBvTy6v2LFRPCjeRXnkuzkPhTHKhDGOxFrO4Ll7y17GeVphPWkV2cE3Pb@NjY8K1uHqSV8UqlXrSgsvMwswy4exVJH9zLYwi8352Gigk541OIWLGK2KnE3qa1@djoZJjxeZiNg/UctVrUwmFF@3r2/EVtEKY4geL62xUKIeEPiOtbtN6Tu0pLS7J0EU6MG@1rz3qQHmqCJ5xLZALapEss6hxMDO@TU2L/UivNZI7l6l8fEj1Q3zW0zQihdvI081TWdJvRp7oBFROTKzPrstgkvTMVjO0uBbjXXbVTsc6XC@3YrNXdDKUz0/jhUCgWIqXupTRCE9AWp7mgZtiRg5c19rN0NSTqWQW/WHjtlVPz8ux2y47qXUasyKejAVpZi5WR/XWspJbtCQhkh3Xs2KK8hSu50Y1ron1TDur07W@mAuNxvnL3KUwveKni6ziYQaF1nL2NJ0IsWJZ5gRdydXNYZIPdmPj4IIvaMmnqza1zHPZIpuOtWP6WOKLo0rLGBmzjiZKydBTeOEx66OadBXO1Js3yqg1rFR0Pl0ORA0hM25MIret0aI3E7L9IiWa8RkvLy4rEVNJLXPSTat8Xew3mCVfixUrOX3B9OjcU4OZmXQr1qg1B72KLpVGMHB6ui1VjcmgUsyhek1x2rDAzNvJq35sYKQvmVipuKi2pIqHuc7WR5mAMdM99HBSDWRWarYYFOfRQf36asLo6Vl/6LmqRenbUUqdV6iw2Q92OGMcr4tst9umtWx9ZRjlWKvnubqWaaEeuI2m8iu22Qtq/emwG@tOLmdP3W75qddu5KE5bzxCpFF@ogbXV3kjKsZ5tt9KpUtJdaYxRX1SF0OTktptBbqip7vIFOZPgSsmNyr02EpluFql@KLeUWKZSa@c5pajVqxNBbNVpn8bFLRiK/PUzQ2nIz5dWvDBGzVveG5ClcX0Uo9FI2woPuOMYHsyaXtiSVnyRIPD5TCQys4iGbqv1ztUtupJd1QVekH9NsJVaCPUr8im0Yo2G9l4PZ1L50tX2RuxFG8UuJsbT/e6kM4mm5Hi1XAcuuqyRopOlYejRoAaldLjPm2asanUkHJG9lLPLIa34@vJtDePzkpGd6VccVNpMGFFTht3Sko0krxuP4WrTDBbprO3K1kJRMOLONXnxX6Rluvjm05MyubprjyECXQG5H98U57qvKgbw3gHal5eKdF0qzpo63l5WAMK5d5U48VJXBoPheAtVacbsVy0I1@JfLVbn0S7PemmWQxGxekC5q/dzOpKzNDQ6q1uYzhlbiJZMF1DoadCZzi5nlXaRj2caTdLtRDVfqpnRLaQLZXat2afrVSZQW5mtqKxfJblJ6lxJbtM9VKFeY5vdfKekSfQ7POzXDspZ9t9zlgsb5k4oyfFERUZRcopMcOa83Bb1EPp4rAa5OSCuqgWY9qkXisGUsXstaiOdSZ1nVx/Iu1lfCKFlwMxmbxsF7rpAZW8TmdGgbZo8HXFMy8QsFRO5n73s48KEXRdIWDUTJX6iPzwvH3Mxdk7B0@Qkyfw6@17505gZ5/dgwRE@/1qoAXK8Tpa@A3hU6sQsrfpx7@cgLcWz17uLfrY9XEC5IbP8UAn5NcSxL2NUIeOM2/I@Cgp7xFAdjzJDgreByOvJ//COIUv0OBdowQ2kTfqXIQ37q/SRjiCz/nAJ3QyD2c7W54udpcaTCA0GaeIwE@v4xf4VIXvICPZAs5Wc@5D2/rM2V5@IM7QFHLSiMPnd5Cs9qkYGNM@Cqs1cfzmbAaKHMiy3lh757egOJqNMZE4Od8DKV7TO7mLP3hP@IQDCabEKRNjqs/744E6nIlIRtqot@CXqyeEwiEUhLIC31kHeLKRBE3Ow43CNYbijH00lXV@JjkrCR/QRY5ZxMd1OhHybY63@ojcJODFl1PH2SspRSeTtRRah3xM7iIPCSXBnE3ulIczxeNxm56E6WE9LhzxHes@06a2J@Kd@UDe2qdPUHn9aj3@pQTs@6uKqKYq/FB1Goj86vPuOyfkILJ1B5pw2m5/mgm8qeq7MSKWJ26y1xFfR@FdYu5FTkldw5lLTcBbd5tTCWQV5BdfPkwjobPX6biGHz7gIzTObN@J3Qp8obRpT5b4U@oD4SfeAsev05@e2ofC8AjL7YcPJE6yIi1akGS4cPLZOpVXtaWdWbJAHtd1Od9BeeHCe6tu77dArqF6IJOP@HetdACzQCz27oEjQE22Rt0WVThcEpTNPig@x8d9hk85QR/XaesTfzA8lhty7s6jiSRySg/czpENSs7AQG77xAkSeyfhl96IK8GF00r6MJpONLL/7LfotTmCf4rzUeMkfZPTb0zxz1O7EIuZIa2Jxi2AA8/4LLgZZwq7TbNuC@z4Rl6@wvXB@Grkl1eAYJ7T9SXWjfjlA4yvr5I8H6zfenUhU7UcKy0y7LykGm67qYFx@LRqp@Y8RcQP7gyiyJbo2U7qCFJxXd9InkDyhDOHbyQPMe6p8VayDsn4F2DfSJYg2Xon8nC6CunWTv8bACb28gRxfTTVR5OTZJd1oAc@CuTZUtgu5PGsGbsRAWQ1jNUe@/mRfTQK@mi1jiVse@IF/ZOIlQWARdpldx78vJUWkooP83ZZcrFTpsUT9AV9tTDbORJY/EhKArWLy3ef7OFHOwRA/wNVil6nrwu3WntT0T358cOwM8CtDcwKoh9/fI8yWxD35Y99WEuf1ULYD3enhha3tnisH6jctquVaWVnOpzHPjpmV7utfSS29Vh3ysBWhVh9a9uvRUnpQxmA@ONuNHZ5cqNP25g74wGdbrTHlo9Wt/g6HwOvpAd7RJEe6UW9bZD/dq5yWO4hJwcjcm@rLPA5YdzZK3YaG2jfPvQFQG@4@ULO@D2ZsXvpz63st9XmCOgjnZrw5sxStDyYhhc2gQfI46x23dUJFrJj56kVj394U9pHJr2BzDpP7xEQmOdAAx7Z1mp8PSZKit96JxX0PBMIeYmLuQXyvGXTWll9C5/@CToXZpw9ZE/xb5HtqyR0gDWvwDf1xvy6eNnlXlTP0vSHK3dnvdTs/OTENKLX8kSk7hOMkqeIQZuDm87Q89f10D@MM1@2zbdn7xiut3XFutHXkvgtIvj8BqO/KmT7VQg8oD2OYxKIZvjKkEQOITw8KG1d6x/XMWu3S6tvv2mB/f/FXf9XGkuy/znzV7T4kkACCCZ39z6/3SCi8o6KC5jEY1yDMOpsgOEwoPJu8rfv1qequ6dnAHXf@2HPPTcO091V1dXV1dU13VWgajNZDpoFoCkgQ9ltldc2106sOnX0xauJMW7ysRWGFKAiFWSyb3quOsd2bp8Xb/etDR3FHHFLcJMdFubYUBbcGNuWzGDTrti9wjALk8FPmtO3YdjLGoNJGwwMwUTooEp5CWdlzSoxL2P0hE4bvepWR/kw6@4mvVnRr3hdoRcwPrVsgoh3tzxtNjFtHPsmiDhDLZdjNSJU5vYBDiuK9lEb6feobU2gVwsbGY2PmGQcuVLreV6JE@ohU@0McTAUwyFb660M3tuBQJ0d2mjH8S15DH4t8DJIDE8d3fJPd@sSbAZF2MR20M0pyNympWZrKwM0VuB//XN1ZW0ajdeug@GaP7wno/p65q0qfyj51jbUdHJT@B0HhSvNg89am/C5bD6ESGJCIwVsxaH/kEUdspwRRTST8yQmHR9aLHuIQcznxvv@fY@sfonYMgqjR/53RpuFUnE6moRcohFx7Dr1M/gZx1Mt8S0ivWPQ5GwxnLhOFvcL5O1MzkoWymIglRFgOeeAuEBLVriZb5kMxg@E6vOkF5deVPQ73TsQAdn7KdspGi6W5F9eZIYesdbAClxeoce@RJkY8dlRoGDrJJrxb@o@fpfxIG/4iCvkXu9TPD4QjJJ@GI4g5DgKivZbxABh/KtWe6/WbBZ18ho5sY5T7nKOGVcEOWAd516wx3hxWh3hAmVQXqGzgC34tmPgrH@ZR0Cr2YSp8AB2Cq8Qj1B6UCjzr7lu2Po5qc4s4etO@lcEXpZ0VI8R2VHgXdws6zQrmGamssOKV89yo9PtIhDEsT8IieKq3@8T0cKLVzE78AiOGPzvLf7oAjgvLfFSXpgrLyTKi1IuRMW1it27cVxpw62UWf0zrvdLZeJq@Tlc24o6XT/h6FLFcOzQvflU3ahIm7Qgrrxjh1Kk0hZsJQoKTsnfF4y@lKwk2lgBt@UXUq7le12PvKUyUfdTEj/@enqAfI7BoK8spqS0OAz6f4j70ZawhlUIqyTNMd4sdjIptUNEq5MCqQkSYp62O9sxlPdlo3F4zmR2tj5litol9Uc2TYZkXZubWAvmiMMlxvmeGffIKwnh4eIVBwTDhKApM3N3TOOZbjxzwKLWikHrmUihyQlOXUtP8W0c6/6Jf8xkTxJn6q0uLnwllD9K5@WmRZJBrHRXMovZlNQmk/HUl5e6U0@sIjHuWRriYiVxEmIH2r2DprA4fbkPchNOh70VqydcRWE0xRzfbYnmdFyhbMR32RCi8Jf3z7V33kFnQFZh339UFdjUHQ7H7yUu20z8aBLRHPCpg2MVTUejfqDjuqkHvs4h/Syv/4bLCDFEx2goenVcEJX6eTzpyzHUqKgagPyAe4ZxQTS9RYJqeIKRa5lU601AICdFrzKccWRiDoO2LldefDVFHFco4D5t@xwiZORk9rDnAVZa0TMXi6SrNzK/hxMygajjIcc8RKjVDc/72zTo/qgeqPVS6a/l0oeywzLjqi4VP3xUdcdEMgXrpXKp9Fv5o@dVw9FMrjZmuznA@lgAwLw6wkL/mWTTv0cuZK9CKwZXjMj0j/zxvd8rel7T77EP@HrKHIEoTyNfoihznFe8IdsK8e7J3B1EeUXbrjuoF/zF@iyxa7scWCPv4Q7RyB8PgoncNArvgx4YaO5N3YT9fvjAjmhcWRJ@oNHAnxBT3uVUkiSOS6tpYduFw8USN5DYgQP4XYf3HEdas4Hs1ADh9/kCkIcgioDgIpN87w4lhK/b7wQDiNMCAhBlKeaAIYC61pt2/Sdp8JiIf5MGpTvWC7tTRObtmJFZI@0X8lyh6e6PA9K@MYN5VLiZQzsNcPuw3lKtxn77S6VZU/R82mx8ru/V9tTuuWof1lS1cXrOGbrUYeOItEtLVU726O1Ju1nfPWs36EWm0qKWGS7wKifnqvb1tFlrtVSjqerHp0d1gkbgm5WTdr3Wyqv6SfXojBbrg7wiCOqk0VZH9eN6m6q1G3nGapp5cTvV2FfHtWb1kH5WdutH9fY5Y9yvt0@AbJ@wVdRppdmuV8@OKk11etY8bbRqCh3z9uqt6lGlflzbKxJ@wqlqn2snbdU6rBwdpTra@HJSa4L4RC93a0RlZfeoxpi4n3v1Zq3aRofipyoxjwg8yqvWaa1ax0Pta426U2me5zXQVu1vZ1SJCtVe5bhyQJ3zss9whcaletasHYNo4kTrbLfVrrfP2jV10GjsMa9btebnerXW2lTeUaPFDDtr1fIKGTcZNcEgblE5Pe@eterMt/pJm9aMs9N2vXGSo0H@QowhKivUdI8Z3DiR3hKTGs1zQAUfeADy6sthjd43wVPmVgVcaBHXqm23GiEkJrbdbqqT2sFR/aB2Uq2huAEwX@qtWo4GrN5CBYIJvF8qhPSMe41xIrrkkYTVM5Kb5@FU9X1V2ftcB@W6NklAq66lhdlWPdQ8p7m85i385PbkB7z5r3zaFfJ0kPhqY69GFp9khsnE789o0fk9@fEuUUYLjS2kn/orKK9VVz3/enp7FQxvQmzNbTP5gj2IbvNIj5RDvtNv3hMZnfWHcm6wunp19blyRfvc1tVVLv@Slgkynmuho7A@VSun@9gPOz3e5id8Sy6jdt7oWO95Cbzs@lreWOdDTq2t9XzdDJcXAdi4iXRSAgLWg2bkW42doXJQ8ifmpK@IM2aknUXm82YY0T/Dn/EPWRucF6Sc5dzC2hr2sEwGMp8oSz8h4aQgOjMInwMIbhhlMfL9H7fZkosOW37toMqZNlx3QtvA22zumebX/m2qeSHdnonFXVM2Vkw4eBOmHYIZ8i/NMqXHpTjmnmXFtcd/coYaRkRGYU5Q8UVWffok@0aaI76o@ApzmzaUOKcDOa58rX/BZq60/nEz9f7Qvpe5hVvnyG1D690Ft7vkP4eXUoEmWIDtF7EkmMkn1bU1pw1ZZWxP2sqIVX@HSg9Bj9ZULNV3Pi/riJAv4YLd9rQYj4NHl3pSwwfNyvHu2f4@aU5Q@/H33/76l01PR9wfT77m5e858CCpJXOXrOiHgMw0LnJmSZXsnv25ZDlOdh@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@sMbLhIi13P1OsoIzDel1nnoNNr79jpYWc5iybYUDYzPBankp5aZvI/6hNG8SrTM6W/yBRdnuzLfg5BTqGEwjdfQIwC4bNPboc12wjnDghd2G9EemEvv9KrOLJVkgrkdVm1OTxH1LnhPTOWIh1LA0E7gBJwXvd0zqZrf/KA5aIv0DmGSAxNZV9zGBMg0b5Ia0YY5ZsrEtd5kX2w1LObEvJqqT8b/hgik7IvLi5To5jIAOWGYC2q4w4ng@q/rN@ZGPl7sHUnib8@5LgqXfleCdcc79wJC3b6r6OYI2RxPsC6pHUo5lKn@wMvM0ZGg4dC8Eh/GFdB99zkNKI9A2esW2T0/1q6IYCspM7Aqsy3oXUibchCtv3amC94krlrn87xpP3M29QpIo7e4MCsNoNAMuwmHNKcn21MXyKsDg6fbpDl9PBQvO5MB53hTWcQ9Gd86vQf4d1wLRpOo1FxNPMymUzSG4hA4AiRQrRPfPUlGPbCh0jt0nSAI6l1ctY6TTr@HM9XVTxfSv0P4VC7jNmbA3@DmElReDOhofE31UwnFx/H7h72E2pPC7u1ZniBwFRjFiDCO7CW8cHJmTrwh/6Y7MFTPnOpjoKuPyT1QcYUn8KM7kTToPo@sLc0drUP24U9O5vKD9ipY317nkagoeUhWlmaikTwWKdVhG9@RqLu@ASL8x2O@9UzTqW7cKSjAcFpCmNTXJw3037eQ@7GL/X2ITbjsjFn3wwta8bXB1@imE4DcdZSZ8ad4WRGTPHSzhsi@znfTVFxMCCC6C1nJ2/qBsjE3oPbrx9RV5EZXmsBXkFoqvrBPZLFsRvuJWPE52y12yzm26aOr5iX9HVGdSRGz4tHL4@cocW8@u2/VduH7KrTfqdLOyzVmqL5hw9kB@6G0QRVjytKldbL5XKh/AEu2rNWpcgTAf@bDGKeVz8@bTTbxEgdIt8Ihl0zwXxO2iWnsYgdBaTuot5/h0I29Uljrn9n5sEEN3F8M5vyxSKzkaGx73bg7qUeRklzmF2ycMmHY04chmhQJEKJ6UhYEfQAKfpYSQKTAz3Pqct08jFZWiydHM2PG3wHbX2Sqz6@h37nxvyOFID/yO@o1Zh3Bj0d9p7GZOAPLPXBxKzuHangpXOeWYaJL5WE423@Lawk4l7OhdPzcUYiQvaAQXTfHZNu6dyTyOEIiwmJRTLDuilne9O5DvoBzQGiq3sXYsERdWUGgl0QbkY0j0fc5trBgsS0LMhWQLOrFw5sVaHK82wwOP1@FM26oVq9pW02dlrRyPd7nClhOpJUACgv0izv08ohYeI24hwB3mqJz02OSdkgJQvpvmkfsWMR6@9axtwzvSGpMuEF23fY1gsg6lFrwpMUGduyC3bYeYXvvDke9g4JBNrmwIglgf4IxCiPj1JEFY03CwQ/sbjkEY6qz@OdjgOIhpyMKBolCwBLvur6yQIDHn3Xj3MVREi3LQGpEIOGGImTJc8JH1jyB/qLc6cImpaVPlLnZjnLzP0AKTTFNxCq2xD/onLRcEy@Efr8jXAucOEjQvISvHTN8nxNqmUTiDg11xfALCyE@WExzIKGqT9W1of3HLANrVgspBcSDTok/QhGxN0/CI3q5bBy/VA@MNne3/bDa@RtIk1B2PBnlo8H1n3NO7AEo91SCSKYzDe1ZbqkSdd3m4ztorZofvg7ast4LHa@DWWgdMG2zCWOWaZ47eLpxI/4R88ofswkklfB6khlrwJ58pZ0N8BmNEj9JrOh4pmJkzhufY052WSQaFJONdHEJZtcJ5qse3Gk0tToogVUP/4me2bsEj6VxCOgtu0AlbxB51F2NyUOQMduGqSMTETEW7/UAoKKF11lY9qh@qUXh2hOfLYXHOYnH8HjE9@Z/8pwyqtSMt/Bozm6x2qAayXKZxwGfJjVHcppNvAPG/45Z4jR/driJkNHU9kOS4GX6PYYd7WyLpbchloddeSrIWpFWNhc1BfMA3ylz9B/71RWIyi4xEolhNXVqpAYz6GXL2grK8Ni9GDJi1dm/uUoOBpBT/Q3HxmTZSCbTcwro7ktTHmc090ECu8FHGPyJP5nRHadvMWK4qiGFgw@pDHVRp7/SNsz/sbMIHj9sR5r/VJiGlvtoYm/iDFfmlUj2YultdNLyaI6zqpiufBUZcNsy6ellZevNsw6@BCg76S6w7ojOIk168wS/DYSlrGVEkw42GnYDURDJdnmKF1pm1@ggJNDbojLp3rlOaHMdQ/Ty4iXWDkTQpJ1fiFNu3otiewEUM5LtAL/lw04jju6E3tpvbLU08O@TCIsLDPuT4mFrWzG/SmxkMrOsD8tFiaXoWUtt0/LRWIkhAU4lKh3DOxTcnWQKXh0az2majFBs0s3lrnfzy6g1tGq2tfpzZlKlkU6dUkSB/95lIFZ1YFGE@JIzLuwo3EZ95bWuO4Pv2cjMuve2y3STia5JMhophMRoNMGA4/RZQ4ps20D0tjiBNN75oGc3eSI9m9lw8J7UGTtur1L3u5NgDWrSik3b1Ca6P0x8VsLiS/MZ1GIt1gb8/nh7ekyTTUOPIXjHmpnvAVffL1nqHrvUJXsnTNCSRYvgVR4EaTCCyCtOZD0xP5A6yU/ro6Rp85/DsS3b/Mw@M/faSOlYZCm7QVwYmMf/NCZPQdzhYytVT5T15FTZbZBbCc/B@OPNAzOC3pnv8bpl3cdeN3@1x@H6awcSzmblJUFFFmqVufJyoMs1tq839X1jKnEe9vij@u7wO4EVp8faYljrBvjKPGd/Qi0moyqb4HF87@8hH95Z1iT80EIT7hhyFr2/s3pUAQjxMMkV8VsA0eRJfehuiDJiKdL08qPd6vp6MdIeLq0We7ZnnwSh4/jdCpT10RjJSTObOFi5WRWK6PfFm3PnsW/uhD/KByRjXOzkACuP4AfX5xSKZUem6aprfWL1rKF69l8v1y7LZWb5OWT/M1c19ep67iYTpN66D/o1f8pyLovZgT@D5b8hZGRJUS@XkgkPrR3tHNLDaeDa3/svWSqS4si/sgeabnket7qqqp0acusI@PDK9bl9H2@RgkzGIIQqekI32siOdyJyQ0fmS8CnK7bCx@GXLuYAQr20Q78zlCHytcL5u0Y3y9s3TzSd@JyF2MIhl1idOQ77s/vkpO65@sSnEh@gq2bi8ceUg2cmop8jEmTJbZmdpbc08rbJQaOtWq41kbaUDGyg4@h78Qy1/YSGea5xS6wl1hPTxlEJMTLUOoNbwr00zK6sZyZ05FlpR2aF7BykbllvdwvMLdmLzW3/gOcTA@o5zxr60EvsBvPKrX0Jt/7Fw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))
- Gaot++ (140) [local](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)
- Floater (141) [local](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater)
- BitChanger (142) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl)

### Explanation

Snuspi is an Interpreter for Modular SNUSP and some [SNUSP extensions](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Extensions_to_SNUSP). The extensions that Snuspi has include forking SNUSP, executive SNUSP, decimal SNUSP and toroidal SNUSP. The one we use to separate Snuspi from Modular SNUSP is decimal SNUSP.

Decimal SNUSP allows commands to be repeated by preceding them with a number. For example `6+` would be equivalent to `++++++`.
The modular SNUSP section has changed from

```
\>+.--._#
```

to

```
\>3-++._6+---2._#
```

`3-++.` adds 1 to the cell in Modular SNUSP but subtracts 1 in Snuspi so we print a 3 and a 1 respectively. `6+---2.` adds 3 in Snuspi then prints twice causing 44 to be output, while it subtracts 2 and then prints 1 in Modular SNUSP. `_` is for DOBELA.

#### Incident

A `+` was added at the end of the brainfuck on the INTERCAL line to detokenize `+>`.

Answer (score 6):

## 151. [Black](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Black), 6886 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1rc@tKkhj4@cL7D/ylDqW@JMUHCL4piTqHT4kSRVJ86nl1QRAgQYIABYDPc9Ux3t1oe2Ycu3Z7PNGesae7x97YiVh/cHh3I@ywIzZi/dXhH3H9cWJj@x/0ZhbAl0TpnDvjhUSgUJWVlZWVlZVVSBTavNH7/e/38CAVTZl3Fc0kpmiYpKPLE1H3k/ScfOJlIxIMMQxCpfTueCiqpnHI7BGOEFkV5A7cE1MbiKq8EHWIDxIy0rWuzg@J2eNNIhoCPxINoo3N0dgkmrQ7W4iQ3FDryz7MOZTVLoCZoj7SRZOmhwlpqAo/bHf4FymRFwWOdEg3SFZUfhj@YBJBGw55tWMAZJSQbDmdK6ZeYIgRcqnphoh4BNEwNIyMEzLLicIL0ASA8rqsFVOl0xdJXICcAun8SBFnhG8bps4LpqypmMSRWqlRq7zMESTNej7/MjZELnyaSvJjYbCVRNugomudsYD8MXsiJCNPJVkRDUaAup@Qkd2SfgyQPaKLfMcCYyRNJ5iFDAcKkYkwGpG2wvf8AlFkgM0H4kTEJiALSFd6BpmNhoDB0IbiJh0GUUWxQ4yRKMiSLNDSiTgzRdWA2hp@IgPdU1lRSEdUIMOaJMELyMjY2IiyCPAzHY0hcAijFxVY3e2LAKOKSyaII2gFZIKGjQYcWfJiqvOjERAJjKwB4aY8BNmTTadBRN6QUbohiyGqHcq/0UruNcKrm7UkE5knPNA71iluQ9SxMf0UL@mJuggo@ZXkuaa6bAILkL0pUhF5ndR1UXRv94GtIqEwDUswsSJ@2nzHx85cOe@EZrRy@PmRyezpofrVOcMTf5LsPx7BL@lwHDG5UpZ83r/HsCXy0NQj3cW7SfLnxGDv70X4zbg229WfGcDKAFcUwmojk@V9IyDQZwKBLI9BDPkmQf9I2SiYHL9oiw3hsqA60BqkoJKml9ZMGOs6dus1U/kBVFrR1C7wEyqrj1Xkh0qiAWgCQYNe6SXiBLgG4k7bSJtSDtd7MjSagU2y0ZEs5UQZCuoJZM/m6LJcQ1PGFA5yGiYKIHAFsiLGgkSaROJlBbNAOqKyqNZFY6yYmGesdrDlQfmIHT9ZkiFoHQQaahMojgekNAL60nCjB1KiABgaQqNVxaQf/9Gfd7pdwJMSBE3v2OLaJB1NoGqUp8SCbiIosJrKK5QsgPNi6VZ2KGDCK3KHN7F4dW4XQYmgpU61sdIhGhSoT2XoWj1@At1RkkTBFC0htzSvlwz5gaU3ZEtyoeJDvg0NSwugZdNq@8inDLSSIDJ7VGZ8w7EpxYlvlCNOg/3O9fHQ9fHDvQjEuf3ug32W7R6BwPkPaBTcOd@TnGZqSzMaJm9ococZzc2epgaJTyAOIamNRNXl3MLh9Dr1ttPtR33mch/JScEvyWrH5QQZT0O5TveRkBTu5MOHoxe5N0sELFPEgr1VdAluBwMah/aJCTvkZdU/mpOmzw5tpGnGI3Ick/0b0ciXl3ETK2KPDjwolhrKB6ghv6GI4sgV8HNu1BIIt7PamLCroi9w2BU@lB88zj2nZ7PqFAPUdKui2FfrsoZaSxn1cGwBpqjGCLS3jqIr8CA8BipxE0Z/L2lTsaaaHxQLVYlT0amLpA16dClGtEdaPQ7z@1BP2hjWPWgJt92hxc5GfwZdAF3aNF4pZUWbQsGUNhy@QIOoWDjfhSaCzFaFUlaFrBJpzHbVBiroFcTWFknc15ahL2CvA9Vui/5GHQE8FLRgAJvVVzZU0JCfAxbBGhLX/YbIEnSpIWgJfU4EEVUP6CDRGlewkDHthgbYPWgBBXzBSGS7q73qaabOpny3oKsX7LsdCiu/2adQ3xBJnBKFV7tjvoumlwpZeEEQR6atr6Amhgka6eWwQyN99hjqN3rM/qeXZdOxxB5dN8pAXW@1nj0i8qhkbOPLp4BOJbxtPpKOrIN2UuYvSweAyYvCHd8jyBYB3zveIGFpCICQiTNRGJug3ECQpz1Z6IHsInWqpR6tsehl8RC1WTooeJ@0KhqJ4U6@DTJ@dhWFZLyJwoct@hoPjLGI6mQrgjb@ZsT7mHljuAOxtiIRxoONWD/L@0H2voBzqKnaDqTAyBVaBNlOsdoBDLIaGoMwfi2tL9pZVxbiqomgzUB7QM8H@euZ5sg4hOFCNnvjth8kha3r84JZVlFYWFOfy6ZmhduK1gb1bED/ZJclsMK4Lc9eVIjGrdqwbzATsMMkgyRhAH8ag9S5nJIBipPGZxB4I8lBFThFYZ0dAEiB/MAol2RQlZwHpVKbq4LL4addyQ@dzuElDuy4DjcEMNeKLxltiFqItKh9gAZfWgfNJYG2snU/Vf38zhFvNQZQ887p9Pc1WXV9dn748MF56DwBDf/hw0cIHWPoI4Y8EPpIQz4aQjg/hmgOLw1h6h3NgXEPzue7JeaZ@wGbbYaj00Ieufi7w8PQg5e/4@xrEK9uUHWg2QDahxfA43Qnkxh0ux0nU6iovy1Zta9anO1QaaiKapcRZyNNN0mpnM09VlL1s6SDHRs6q8htVoXx9XEIPRjmMo4d@WFSsswOwaqmmUnaYBhPofMAZE/6GFMbQ5@H@Yc8lM0Cnf0oKgr2utGWqRkod42gIosmY49Ga1nHidC6baAeFL6wOSeSdG240nAGIwo9jTj2Qw605bfmtTjs26lhTB3bs9qN@BjGD3FG6heYriAQn2bdriJtwDgC4izVD5M5puvxICSdta4ibcgERYkzV7/eXkZ@5gLPGL@atm6MI5sYd6W/nWmFnKPIDXVsjDYq95kL0viJKUnYRVfRIRo9gKkvakDK4R2zdRs8irAdrS0qs2jYJyqS35wt/KhcomHGuhBf5y2IHXmZ2WJXBsYETeGbSS8SeJ2xKKzDiFeECQ4pygZd3NgUCmbVne4Zh9XdQ9tjmWOdElwbnrutZccmFir6IE4DDZXrOvQIpmFkCwVM9l/nlGSjR09boK8oep1CcxvDtkRPOwAObQsMOhAuByBLznEyiUagphFVnFIwOpZQZMAqWeXZKr3gqLKLnu3xcYuYtiiNYYLJtmUVw18A8yXiFFJqt@W3QIEvSPryugNMH7d3sQ2Eq/fKhCJbjDfHuqmIHfv6n/@gAw3wunl6/BwmRsJgFXgEvmFT@aQ3W8vOijf0tLtlKUx/rMg8ZQMNfQmlwOPklVdWgd2oUYETn6/H69C482XjgnDiCXr6O3JmUa6LyrgjLq@7C6Es3jbUrNyqPKQ1gitanXTUfSP7CzPTyo@Tf13R@A7FYi3KyOK6ta12EWd8FyrHbmgk0KdfQefSGiTrVRgwe8yxdcaFly@1qzzC326uHG4LWSDCtzkRJq18W36Dj0hG9C3JtjoMGio@SeEHVvARg7sra1VHl7tdMNDs61tgYI3DhGnECyI7pZd3xGI5dBBqFvDv4dQV6/wWyHLNeRV4CxCqqtDTTxE@Kg4C9BCUHVz@9G2wSX7BWIVvz9Gg6/10KcIC6ZgMSiYpeDyBEA7Pq/nyeqF1NHo7P9oTNH8isTu3tSZLEQiaJInil3oujD7ykFd8wc5G8E1FvDSA16EdoH1@woNprPAGCIlps1mcQLPQ03uCiwOKgOKyDr0jtmtylssib82s13lGsqApsjGizb28eUsjvpyTrNHgqjs9rbPi3Wv@dmAagIO1bxXa3ak1wcTZ7Rty9BVKyppY4tR9QzD82lu8E7Qp/t40E3raRLTOuweuxU6qvkIF@RQqGTC1fJ29I3xJXHGZlJ52c3GwkypTUHbGH5JLTdN7omqQoD@AZo5K1/Zh2FYUa6ZbL5TflmlDVjSD1Oj5PV7A9MEwrPNuad5km8yrPqFn9bFVeHe2nUTRQY6k6PmNxuWVrqZE412Wh9ObEjDWJdT09vVrNdxKQ3HcFzXUyujRVM6@vqnaB/D/JeGgq7Y6LmZsBN@xpXapM3sS/HYFYV6AK5S7K5cPxGlOP2vN@d5qAF3oTfn58vo3GD3e4u5y9BjNqckMNh1mSMQhYOqWGf03KS38fmmdr9NRr9DGvlSJjcYdKCJobHp@1aQkGOB@Yg4uEPh6jSUpY3Es7tQg5XZfxGe97@iOrycqYFdj314lYYF5@EB3BbWwJ4RfRTWO53j3rsLhFRk6@RetmZ2qZgR29ggn0BUIVDDwOmNXHY@2GneDd9WxWn2fc73RsmdrnS0iMeWnaqT4l22mLVPcEOnvLbM9N9Rg2qsNwYZQv6L9baR0Qck6byGmMWvMfRnXtvR38R6S1aon2K9gj0CrygPDhwtkX6d4gm/N1ylwIgEzMlU053h@i9u7FGlb05Sf0jqgTzsymmlgfKJnw5da6ZXtYy@Ak/XKhIGrHG3prTUJa6yxJ4/APZwov9nQFaiSSQeHr2nlVyuG74xaG@uHX5pDwohNF34MXViG36K3ip2b88f9sXcJXq6KscvAe8gS/tDX2EejpdFLl2dxSddaxF27Zuy90D@jOXBK7vgMoScORXr7jsXPd/pjY3l5E2im4W9Hsp@lC6xv5BvJ0OFVPG8tGG@YRKamigZr8npXxLmKIvJgjVqxbynZ5brtTuYWhnxXzH9RstbLDvhoVNDlreDuBYhD62mFANm@oEasaaCmDsS5sbzuNpbnArTnePgutl2dXMDVzS/2aj@7c636Czaf2tN6ak/s6bRnrO7e6hsgkabl5fVeJYD@Hm8M8FkwVUjrOV7P2OSuoinK13AXFaKlHjVt98JrDn2wOpD1J@Gd821IsC9fXKODcZsyiQ7gb/WdnjiG4cnQTG0k@ujdW6AKrvBY591ryYWy0yAtWdQ7WBOUxSEULbcVkUxlIKFvbD4d2L161FY0Ht0N3rHggTPL69esRwmavtuSO@U1E4zT90fcPKXnS@NyWjbRNaD7BcCt5mmLvKnKA9bu3/btbjne1ra0ajLxZTHar8jADH3ux1ZObqbX8FLY3bPlou2d@W61MmNdn39ZKs3e2FrSx8BbSyv2I6Sd5GRqxS8rRPth027Vp/Dv61T7GSX1aVu5PRhe2xkP4mTddr0yVv6NewVV0EXqBLF8KE720DVjPBwrvKnpfkLhXC7e43G7GSsTLnV0VQBbQlEPM3Q7sZzXDKLIhklhZYnc3ZH9z7PDwCH3TJLEceggDw8WVuoAkZuNqGtY1cp6t88/JPedPp9z33mvHpKAk4KKCsw8d4LyW3CSTC8WneuqE5UfUk8XDC9remS50xg96rEGst2B3tYA04kuk2m65RRieR7V8fnIf/qrju3IB2OlQYayATONrorOp9pQ7GnTj1a5dump0YhHR0DEMe3hAwAs3ZdJEQN0BdgG1H9Pm5JGvh633YFs91i4qaBAbFBhNSpabeikZlqNZlHT0URLLOyCV7mWlRI0ZTxUQUN1zJ7hJzXQWyJ1N1o9IIYQgqmmjmq64yUF0hFxZbqDhFHLRNG0AX3yjZT8p7@ynKAgUUYRwvCyeOoDuVEiQWuLeh4JgjYGqpdIFqKu2SAuZDKMjmM0@kGoRSveTYQeT72zQBJ9S98kLMbyT8qkasSXI0704UWPhyNZcu2nqqfNu8BD8udkyIr/@Q9Y92ebb46f@WJRw@ElS5CjZ5SrzeQIJK9TncSxP3PY1UJvUeocuRIq24XchWHaXEtfoyF1NKVyJ06prxF9hK/i4I8enKoB/QNu3RS11WmS@66xZWH6aiaJoKMzGG08hCzXVOqzh34zmGV/Rn4gPZQVn0C4SADuLIYo6Ko1TKaXTxdDmw@A2azYHtOHIZOgPxhK0ursPyaPT2hIFzsaek7efXc/CwZ897NY7oE1lsy5v5/9LBC8Bu5pMPjtf8tiB8qVsp/3/SeBH34w@DlxOJ6dR9YDcejl@58rhUquVk/VGzXg5rNV2b28pg/5taZAWRiBaoPuo1CXVGCLLovGl7XHSoOs7gDc5SL7PDlG53e3e5WwArVZ7fA59q3gCgSswM3cX8i@K78hbqS/BrA1kyQTW4uSChUkW2acxqYG9S5lC9sFu/sYdPaSI@idsEMVUh45SBK45AMufSWPyOtaWi34kUZAM36ZUe/j2IUCeLWGeA2ATFqVhfW10q3K7az883@DGo9gXPvb1pjieLfGCPFejQFwnY3myKcKxUY1t50JxGn9/gFY2jq@hiLRvmV5MlvSpdles0vNRI1Uw/aOW@lWg0xkgxqxKG8SjgwwD6TdkT4TNVC7EFRkfpJSDNDknQ6opvbcRM0GKt1P/WAsZxifShx7wCz/aqD1EgeDsEbytfckaK6pAFrseyvzPoWjmA1mh7f3vcj@@I/@3PLwvjch/Id2eBZIw90f23cShP/hMoXj4O4fr@6CcPdL6@47Fln52p/Vqs2KicjAZqFCDGpnI4uG/Gyj9ji24dgpq2AbykPg9YSyDsGtaq05s8bjumsC56G5gO2opFEv0/JE/cGF3oiHLIumCK6M@KnXhTgTqAVOnROfxuibD0MJG41EwxwYpqJvskToky2EvpGF0O0@BKlkJvIo@X1bIMfHx8RhCLwiJqNHFsvZff67kOP7FaH7AMtYVssdgTyQZZ0D0k7sbK593sO5MSt2TifnJA9HYJBYLQhjmosGAMSN0arNDwcMmprNKhAPVZyZVPHPl9YYmEIqdTITrTc0loh8gMjCjS7kL6V8/TAfnZw25N6/2QyOFoLVEOzQsUvI7r4j9@a9@mC/SUBAYH6zQ@RUCP/RjtcLVtKTeu3Y7nrplo61IZ9qqoYOHnmglriCbDDEclH3Rp9y2KiAXuxBPwBK6DPQBwVR7msjI5XJFc7Lldorx2wK6XwJ5iTOk2PPvc/vvXtYBZwvpH7J1HSerV2m80tWblK1XiNFiPVC6Usyd5X2ktI3Sm9ZXhSvy6YJrwriAl@LmC5K@PL0WcJr7OtUdgMwYz3lfVWqy/35@e7h@ORe3XtV/A@73lnZ8x@gcEHo3qBvrDjJDp1TWPqG1PHFRMO/dDYMOtZvZK0cMq37dfTbrtWr1xzX/tVLLxT0rQ6esB1xwqpjRWH8b/inQN39rFUUdS62CFvSC7pmSSqHpK4LFJhX69yb1BC7Lq/fyLR9TFdMKlsTWfruCK/CHEaXBQvaoAramu7SFx1gwlMw13MkmHfhPJpOBed02gOqYvXMvCPTFTpeX/qHrlJq4lD21Zf0oOJY@0uDIkM/4B7UTZHbR3zybkZWvpbvuVL7jZEimy70YZ75cToJtXG5sQLcsSKiC/Rx4sH2tyZLt2gP9ayujIFfFW1E1lP4rLgMVWEWR7JjQA5iIJLz8RDgJHqpijhKiKSk@SAz8NG5JOIOSnHZdfAPOxEo3d8TZx25CyONy@0FlfQzjlv7ZPNuD0y9naCHLVadojPAJmN@kh/5Bsf4O94vqx1x5sJ3hg4fkDsQ75y2Jk6345UMUGd227O989KrfakseNPutWuP8BcKIZFYKYLtvpNI@HsGg76wMAOBEmumXoQgjKEuaciPiGtMXwswiJ/QW9e9S/Uapu4mvhMcz6ZEJR4PnbvAhSb4Cc0p0ZCs4OqbC1@mc7FJaGeMNdQOXhbyiNxxfv8DhGkhbrKPqw8ZMDdw3u5mwDSFLIcULQzA8HeIFE1hloYUWdd9WiyDSwc6QO1Mph2526MdEHhBa01OviVrbbDugRZXE4lDuzW21WGCgFgc79AYgHaHmlvapsBf26ERuIZKDKAyMCmVQaF8uhBVFfqrC2RmCL2T8GMQMt3tXb4R7l2/JEhL2LNIPLM9JIHQ7ZcHc87Pigb2zD57RGfAR88w7n9/jwO/ZA/9c/bvsn726LNrX0nOWTDG3Ceu/V6S84QOPJ599cC1r6I58u23OHF@3gdr59Hv8DtmAOTbV9xHIM9gHSX31aN9/ti130kGD2gOuPV43J8hw88N1v95n39m978Fa8ILMbrVO137hhu7Q8Dv556BPuwh@6wXZOazy0Ec9H1uLH5f9niQBv/@IxLwc/a@5qHjyn2NpXP0I9vIZbvDpRrZtlVWLfHq/XSLgXb04UqjR6inu/UQ7HEJvPnu4I60XfbR73@/x0VhuvUxGnJpno@RwJHHGeGOnHtk75ODPXDojs/3Wd@EiD7nHS8F/U8PlUGlcu2@d4FsOvcyZQcXdnx3wDJ77EHghxjLfv/992CEkrsT/4n/wX3ncz7cuZYTqZNY7MAbjR94PzkfN2dublcw6AZW3d/HeP7AEw5@Uo9yePyX/@O//Oq//An9@xX9/QdZlkdGpwM/rUcGZAHHQCL4T8OLzkaYx3BbWrjAfgezLoki9w0cXMXpjIScte/wrZiPH@CP/sOxusXzBxpjR1OQ18cHwuydCHuLPY7j9ub07xHD9JjZh2/27sFyXPD@G9zsIPrh0zfAO9FDj8PDT2sWsY5Y3KFpNKYHJUSItocG/vqY@fBg9mZ1Hv9IvY1/VRP/mgP8qwr4R3zpAf4VF/i3iyBm7@fJpOfdg@yI8/sflyFm7/vj75N/iwPrw@zBbGfv5OTh@dnju/N/5zk6sv9BTxyt7vCwQkDAg8fnOb47PvafnMxOfA8nd8zeZ2DJM7MXdIA43x8we8nZcZVSeZc9WdZm6yhCzLHv4a5SBEO97g0e@/aC@VTGG6w10nsc3EXWt5gYwttqLpUtNwC6UsylarnTQjPXqEC88fB48umTxw9N8wn4c/IAFM1@5jnxJE3TJLePB37yFcfjjpB1y@xlT2YN1ncMRBeZvSotyed/PHn4gdm727tzeT56PgaUwCTADbjBpVZe/5fLM0iQZ4G@pgd6gR7XAZklAbERmAfms8BQK3MdCIrwFxhCUA5Is0A3oAZUjoP84XK0/GkL4Rv/w7J2WdYAnwZ5zVnARNQBCa7dcvkSMEpQeh/@5EAgMAMyZ4EJ/AcUqxd99xhAFRG4v2fuiON7ERSMn3P6A05/1OmUHyLR0dPn52D06Y5aIZHEw504k80HB/E6H@/vEomE8@FojzXu71lL9TqCYccRgjw/Pz5mU/XU4yOLyzez433PJ4/vExzJE8@xffm41zk5@nh/6EPhtgTc/7jHHn@8Pwn5MBz1AL@DEHfMen7isUYJ1w/3jNM1bbVa@GtNJ1MrRANW3H1rlYqnFgtRVgij4EBQdlf@7cDstXy5XHeRh8/Pbrf73nnktPjkchERLHeXg7ufBSUSdLipSZ@A8ZALodUVjbhPTqIRuI/G3T5XgCZbWe4do9Ho3uGnSwR@6tuVTKZ0nZ9ToDAMyfcOXn@8d9wFH5LJRIRGR3yJKNF0XyLkdrjd33HHx3YZQTdEO5wzh6Y7yefnzT/X5@djFz3c@Od2Y6R9PnG7INkdgbvZZ9fs2HXswjiIwlyfn08wSOE@Q@jO5X5wPz9bcXB2uY8tnCduYBuug/w3/NcMYoyIc@95D00plYQjbld7LrrDUVfck7D/kh@gAi5HyBmCejmcvPPu7tNB6CAWvvv4cOA/wJ/r@P7kYYcKd8MADh1mKeBJbg/Zx@z5j6oOLuhwosAf4RMQTRH9itYlocQR2JqJI2YPsjng2AN5JC5yfHK8EpL1UOM@gR75mVCuEfcDcT9/BsGxEsHUctlPK@7vZ4EAHeDJUTu5/3mPfz6i@MmzYwluyx/F73Ie0cdZjs@OfV6/4x4cz479z@1ntEkPODc1fSLho6ODsBWOxSHMHbitFVqwXY5WYUgRDV6gHf1oD@XDCUx0Q62SbbErq2CHbnYATyQS@cAG4TL7WTQXnB3Yx8nBjiMejHsOPJ/uDsAEwqZ4oLE/fGCO8FmR9WDK4XNY3YjEE5SIPWIYCQL67Fjcr3hmy7@D7IEV4vCX@2AwMJ1qg4hMSSwAA7yCL7hokvTBiod5IWmLIpjmoqLg6iZOm2D2oHSmMFX/wOxBGwJVkAzHsMKLY1GcjsdTcXVkZOOQ7/dh1o/Hj7/5xY@/@R9//O0vf/ztL3787a9@9@tf/QJ@fwW/X1rXX/7rRATPv/v1P/5ffvyL30Lkf4Dfv4ffv/vdr//ZH1g/ev8f4fd/bcT9R/u3AWf9GMD1x7/79Z/85e9@/Q//DH7/wv792cvfj3/6b63//9v@w@Bvf/zT/4gn@@YXv2T@@t/8Bv//5N/89b//Df7/r//yr//NP/3rP/5XNPDnVuD/@Rf/2jr/17/3i//63/@T//r3fv3G@Rfvnn/9FfG//v8h5uvp/Bo8X1Ovnxrz678RPX8bbqxLAYH61R/9@M/@Acjpn2L470MY/onHZx0eG@APMfKH/UAAzJz7HzYhf2A5sD0IuxH5h@SHe/Sa5taQgP@f/8AGwEYKWJArnJuQf/S7X/@Tv4TYHz4RiLMh/8Eyu61vtiBXdKL9bpX1hwD8Fxswf/jjb/7gx7/8H378zZ//@Js/ZjiC@6x9IB@YIMErnjCSBmhodsBEQqDWlmFuHQ6FaTgC512mJj4K/PhpK8rCfbALmAJ@pOkfdlquWMbBkrZdhX1Y5t@J4SP5BMlgsVCjZYZnvIEYDNOhjl6WUTMbkN5bMPb9Rk4rxronG9m34zFyI@PysivaSqBFLoGIjWxmF0rW6O1qMEvKLODZqwiG2NVjmBhpVOBULZye1Teu9Vwqc8ZESbpcyr64RGygCCnm8vXVbcxKXWaNrFDc5IrFl7f25UY7PEz@nAvHGLjC3ZgIPA5AdEuVGd30zH98DKLOMCeffcfHzEktV4eEeplwwYCfObkmMz@pVK58z8wJrt8lrYGRC0c/@wyDYXDU/EAiMa/X7/fDCa9eetCrf/@7JQj39mxpz8EFuIjDESXBmMMBQ6Pvo2Mukh4ZkhA5GgG9zCU@x0pwlgOSjCghpIsJdLmAoXaqUo@XNu7KMx69HQkXjMKgLnd7JjGn2grAMAywxFc2@tI@X9npLdLmefz91ANKEDcP8/0I0yqDxr1KUV6DM2dgcQxxewx0qDRxQUeWSIDxY0sFg4l4JJ4IBePeeCIejnDRSMTLBb1cLB5LBLzA@DgXjUcSnDceToTC4XDCC00fScSYPVHtyBLLwrybgwk4XmVVwBe5j/GNeM3fO2H2OqKEzjlk5uq4yV5nFTGOE0cofh8gkNHBRRl8UH4wS8IEDl0IQhzhHIyDJwLZy@czgXze4UjjDWjyQCbgcHTwJhIPBGJph0OkKZl4KBCETD28y0UD@FaMQ8abTCqfRwx9vAnGEYfDMbBSrBtleRMDMBVvQiFEQByOpxW6ACDXLIriNJdp3QQC6YzDMbbIi8MfwKWsuzAlNoc3mICZ8lZKBtIcjtNlJhigHI6qBWcXdbasbyrlcBSsm1QKUZzTykesSl3gTYoekEmHOxBeh6MLga4O1qTD0YYgirDDIUBImPMQN4QQepGrJu9wzK16YE0cjhmF5oWBw/G4jIdygJ6zM75ndsSudcx16ypAUgGS5Nk4l2@fnra73bY@T@VOqzTp/PyM78/HervbtjO2H@HQMBckDYbzl4eISY@PvLI76QKS1BdJj/NHkVL4yD8BZfbRxYKGj@eYdA5Ju5bDbIRwDAG4jUd6CNc037aSlgdNotdZu@04AqFlsPeQucv9mS5OuIghL0RQOq6Adwxz5sjHcdwRjTkOD@Dq@OgIQXDmIgEnTJocznuHw32XePjoiEUch86PH33Ob7mPxBFLOA4dsZiDuI900RzrKgkePWM5i2TgCK9PLjzzXjy3cfL12YZrHz2j@oUZ2@cn18KT5LwL90ckDOb4wbDDfQiEHj2z7DH2fuyucCVLlU0fuABc3OEDPU5WAJaaWPVz4vOBEifwA1sG00dJq84uR8KFM0wgKJG4d9A5obUU7nI6Y0Gn0@08AiQfiMMNM0OLTqSd0resPep4qH0i6FhW3pXwwVSZ@BJA@Sta9MGhYfI6PhShRR0SRzThwGjc6TPxagz55PVx3sODduT45O@8Ov67v7Pr2B2LB2ONclGO2XtmOvgqeDhBjnCG/Zl5/vx8fGIXekHmc97jW9LwLSFdzz6z70QWOENbizWpZKpbTS0nzqkMs@cLaWFtb39/n9k7rp84Qo6y/3G1EHXC0pXMe1zmxGVB//3j8QfP32iVyuc/@bRcjwXCWUYX0Uewg/uMWqtF8Qg2SZcYe56/4QGFMEnAyRzh8oNjD/ueoED/i@Gbr1aFjn@@R1eTSOWzNFbpQ@LDS3wk6OIPa3R3jrsHkJqfl2TlczzkO6EPVVCqQTieR7XEd7Hv4t9dNsqNcv5T4DB@GKecvL@3m9/LOTknbZnHTzCAydUcs2f8oEW4n6vnR3uHI2co7AytmuM@uWfVnYu5906CMb/Bz/cebH9nVxgiH6znX0Fur7V9TLduJnQhGoqK/91OtysH/@7l9z/ss6zTuSpq/@TzVxzPd8fHz8d4PNsBPD0/Px@/@qeX9fEGzDr9byY2/se9h5/7jq3/YzhlyhZzHNGIw40e7MZ3j9897oE6SRBHMOLAGQNrLU2MlrbJgUr/ROMA/75bRxxA9oPVnXh8QCInMJPAOJZl791XQTBcEoloPLrH/J5l33PpgNTVM05JFHVjPNz1kDOly5c8PgBWVw86IXA5Xog6XJe7li5NHII2Dj7FRyNnM862ezai6Ga/23Fzg0WXU4wFExm3haW7ThMJ9akL1@5M6jpIDnCrZfSsdzOfmW8A11gwqbcqnI4Y5ht0m8Rb1xLOS741TDc6igXczDff2KODYfoN8xGRYyY70scdMc8MsofvdAyCz5@p35fljs@jE6I2st6vVObEymTQUc6y1qgnPZa7QfABkSwqoDYHhJZIKcfKWcV/Y4G1xxKSki8Uc5CHJIlE/Rjs3A69jZvq0ep9kNx24SQAUYgFwSmnKDgCAjqIdFHc7iH6/AsuCukhHKZL1B8CoMB49VJKvESyM97h7QNkR/SSoGgGILZKd1k1IAePdrF2HZaDLlYCWIi1o6MaHZz1ruC1Ww/3Hbp7cJPPS89iF6aSYxJcuz7buKAxrP2waUZh2LEEh@5WaLOZYuMevNC0R5aHqmsFZ8esGfXMHJje4ZHVVKMj5sIluD/j8/Kjnw@//Vb4bnQ3fDhyD5MmXj2eIQyxA5dsgRyYyWESxGN0Jz8cmXcej/yQHLovXHjvPhqCLfLMSBazDbddN6i5mgRa0KfGcHsXd6rv5@qDN3@neoDksffgNrnw8smAdwY/GewTxfuU5Ox6QJlmcuFRj/hj@OGj@y3vX7AzPPzRVhRmGbiU5OKOf0gCPxTI6PHkoTJAp3GneDwPbihcgcTXGY@Ub7/lPcrJ7Ejx@dwI9V3oY/7OhMCDJ4n3hy7@ePZxcTeG/IcuuCahGMUNxEM@m9fPK9qBviPgsdWma9ItGmdI3gzIGyaTB7cfD24Pkh8@LO5mvuGD12L/YWAtDUj8DIk/2vCudh3cuskLltBVeJfjZ/Lhz/wHBnF4ZY8HmOwdbeS0KDy4hZSRx7Ok@hn1Jd2md@kWghJmewRbuxrSHc3ocxu6m7BBd1A3O/huBORNGYIs2@DWSy0jGSbMPO776yWqpvp4CoFp9rbhmHg/@/iRWRZtO6FCyahc2iLhceJNd43V8ZEA3YLeeqntS/p1lxpe6tzVfLNWuM0RmNqGohvdlaom2uEMXbhDEFQDnwPPR5bGslyPQdlQ7QEwVHsgnA@1CDLJ1hM2ZNJOhNZaNhDkQj0hWS/14YZ4BuontIRXPR9UiEUGdOYdZMjefpLqJpAnGUJEPqblQQC6CvMNVAJpwDrID@QEFBn59lti3x4nYboew7EAwRCu7@EQ6BWlUPhXUAo4kMo@yCjqQ1oI0PYNpqBr/VZB4b9dQfabMS7I4Ol7rRdk/PQFGddYNaz3wpBvbosMbItvvul7kmGbIPinUwzID2nPv9@zh/tDkilfVhr1XPUyVYMzzJDi653JD1d7WL/auXaEO9K2ZZW6hwt8lRNvzgVCXGC2mrhlGe5Q3yHnjSIJBktZL24wAqzfsxbUYEA9XGESDbp5o@HX9C47lQcyu/0tDNxNnHqi0y9v@JZbiyM5dHBW1m@rrV9WM3DRCwZze1eErY8bDEXDsDfk9S2/cUC/40Df2xvi62fQC@0NfKmT39JPiXrF4VMrL/W11OWuTDeu71kItvLTvVZNKzvtHwxuvNvhTR4lmknEA4FDEvBigFsGgstAaBkILwORZSC6DMSWgfgykLAD3BIzZ2GG6WwoFF0HY@tgfB1MrILhwDq4xhAOroOhdTC8DkbWwXVp4VVp0TjFS/aW3KRdV9QxjQvHl2n4tqlq0sgIoOFeRoaB0OArSMgefhUJ5cW3I2OJgF1QgS0jUDAYXd@D9lnCJl0WVV6LDq9VsnVnR8JYxVjTNCqwOV0HrZSb4U7jIHTuQ4Jv3zAMqF0iKCIPxoBogpWSzIP8i@5D661UfX64fgMHMSS51T1kx514IQ9HN823xGdHcnBXsoUtuBOb9VovWTFm4/Ulm0iLysOtkdbCGN6K28T6ARUscvQNiKAFgW2w/b7Tssy6Pt5ZZOj9IrcQ7izyFVEW3siuXMgbF0WeXGal4z/FllyWZ9kpIm1tMAPsL6RQGXjRoPh6cvIzd@j43a//7H8jv/v1n/yW/PgXv/1//93/jOF/i6f/HWwWElwB/PJP8PTP8fRP8fQXePrTjUwUPnTo@PHPfgO3/9O/Ij/@4k@spH/ylw5veIUIUjBqnfNXfx9P/wBP/6fDG1kB/uqPLEDM4vA@M1umlQugfvkfCIHSEMsK2Z/9FSEODxgYLlvy7qw@/rDxMqOFYMWGOxp6eJlunYWejmwPuD0OwGvfces7DzaAewO5zuMnP9Z9D8wZyzUetbTACz18Yc2O0gy0fwQ0YTTD3wV5m3bA6LFXNpxQ@79HDonTgzAQTd/KTlo63K6/XW/HOhVhPQ4WqMNdtG1UGHavKIHpLQPyTWcCc8OP0xY6I@UsGbH5W8JPCi0HEMdSsmTTxbkZu6xlbpj0EPvLDPC/nuqi0OIwZL3VTL@QwthvVHEbBW6pmxfNBqW8jIEp4/o9x82sNEIcjqBJINuK38hYvKFc8L5Et245u9vkyvkXHQaPNpiYg02NtCooSRyOL8Aip214N1pcoW14i14b4C5wGHrYemtyF7Dj@vrawWzEBVCG9I6LYtiolKUyVkncdlJwIym4kQQ0WziprokEgy9ooAMH6sXtN4StbBsqajvbWriw5yzbAcmAuaC1oOmVlLHRS75GTTXytrJ7jXwDJfeQtPvJvUp1zglxuF9lAJzbeZIv23I36sArmNcNtTsncnsrZqu13sa0lWejU1DuMS@5tGo5LrGr5bYLfAc19@D5yoKCgb9lQb6vLCga@XJBL5sV826hf5u/X1Y7SzWx0vBrZFbH39saoHBo/DMQvbU6Qop1GnS5YcqTsqc87alGXDs@wQHx7HJHsa3vbugb@4zhJKakmaK1PPBppMGUQ0MreOO7Xbs@1md/JqurarpobL4NLVvvi6lOfB9f0LoqjGpe3NlMtj8qg4/hrZ1XtseV1chmW6EZ61NgiNpiFFqej4@yKpuPj2B8KpJ7zUC89Qv4Eo@TwW@IQWgjv2tl2pZHLg13aDTdX8ZJ7V0rW10WBq7yyE50QiEpAhM6QVRg8kV6uLuMoVkswSrSN47RIm2bLjcysacNta6oargVAeZ@gb6wxo0E8aMRpcVLeC8RNiiyJ9Euwcu77awXPzkruQi6ePcqf3AbwRYzvER/yWPkrL6juMc3i7OyLcur/XR6a5v01t6nV5J1w3xJM43E1R68/rSiQ641BgBckxH6Mhlee/eRV@RskbKKxk/bWBm@msSOaAgw/CGlKQBN2eB@CeTDu7oz4G5FePMt/r/fgMvsua9tPmrM1uagb4Y5tP3oFM2gey@pgugC8IIbdc/r4lainf3KsuyJDp3heYmDKi4V3wWDjjkaiarhWEIuEX9B5tE/6JXcU6ehpJW4gyZ94iWD4NtNlH3siAo/FzsuG9K7gXdZ46rId6i@@rqKo6KjSk@zvmfkCni5LVOMvrNLgQ7fEBneO3G73xYrC0ReSQ99GEcpLLzNP7pw91I14yJo0noGoumgQffotj50M6XRfDS33vNXrM8o2nrUGn@slizh9gdfZAjwwfpIHuddF@t@T31WXasqfcWIsIL1b1cZX@VdYsSXaV@34U9j0ZdrSlcZVpmSy1besk7eanH5vRbfkIqlTFpWydeJ5JeE7qtlbkPULGRrFZb5aUPIK8wZXlEEwbWJ0Yp5t8U09ZVOwDhsMU19Y1R53KFQVzmppjPxCxNJy75wMzIEC3CdwLUJV0QIc9BHS6CWdUO7drnkRVOG/GjDarFj7gS0RTe46N58jrgBxSzDuJD7vCpTeLNM4VWZwlaZqx6wXeQGECNsFWm3AjbPe02giJL5hnbGJJy5w@U9tQ2HqvE6Pnv97JSdh7KXOCfOQ1DITtF5mHOBUnZ2nIdZGjCchzUaGDgPLyCw7lvOH5yHy26BADrc0sAnjLdVON4LzsOMy/3M0I/nLsv1Ow9XbQowH61bypFna3m1bT/111arqqLotYxKL0GJMeCiYbXuHrz0F4B/CmrvlQeJH5IkeECBcQKyNWhsjBhWOTBs@OnXOV27ho/D5dKUvb6xXkOBdE9yY1EFpWRM9ZFzz7mtjCzCMJUuPsIVCES9ebibIsK9mpl9iRy7dJBQ2sjb5VPu@ak90HHR9DsA3lzEUdb5l@21jcJqwK@jEzO/RecrcpbFUYrQGcC9gyxk6vfOdyqFbf1i3zWr9Tdb6PUaATaibwlitRJFu6HTwYZD25QWNtJG20JCU/Fpn7yZBw@7U6L0vshGtYLdM99IptF2zVAxbHZ@93vV2ciHpG2pIEy8CzxYvWw1LlBdjElrXbdhqVqdD0jY0DkduhGKiGKbtYMUzlI3XjpWvDUMLfNaRVLNta0mIbMfX8gc86ZV@vq5DL6m@dOmr8ucYIIDjYhgI@eqFEu/aj/Bftcs@31pUC@Z8KKAXYb17qH0tXn97ij7gnJlXezrBsREL8m6dxpHqxLWLIfZwYZl/p6svTLx8cNjlpFvFbrC/sLaX7JtNSf4At9ezi0sXGgl6JPtyAEuzA6CbzPqtUWiTPxLo8WPJdl4rIqvKF1X7X1arYrvamJMwTEaLj@5gfXtBt5sPMRHK6C/YLnVy/Fzr/Q5xapv45r6xpML66mDhl5iq10ENyJB3VP/tZWLFkSUH6vZcql4A4NuLBZzv34Ugb0W8q7HcebdxwSraUvQixtB0Y/Qo@9ET9PND/eq47VLGY0AY4Cnz20s8bP7uNvWZRv6/EXfhXwW7AZHbVyDdTfgt7QSmjo8DtmyzVdr03vXAW8jWZq3wG8vna3hUyOUDnyg8/hIh6/HR3TOeXy0RzFsmtVjpN/v2d@9C258SX5v25uJWlzGq91WcAFgPLS@Y24vwNn7qFh@KHuAp2Auc69yjVVTXjo74PoQPqJaeUa4QhyuThSkVQylA50yXMEwTmGDEXy/3cqF0LjwSV0r7XI@WIYObidsjDSVbghJN9miZjtubmwsl14p2WN1ylM3EKsU@lr@BkWWQ9byuRj9Cjj9zID1yXVetZaQl7zxErHrp098ggmYcgzkkbVP4Mr1w3DTTJRg6qMFPG4r4hC/xA2yu2M1@VKGVunl5W4XBIm1v@RgObjU8ePcPk3yZZb73@yRJv2eur0Tq@0TRndBtteBgZ2urQ2MDBKMgjWV8AJn1z9gLLrJENykKECdtCgU/GJwiVnBuHcj7wfX3L19Xe7swrkR3wfXI7as9U6nrONXGya8usFn@1XPjaVp@6El1QMbTy6Xe3Ex9t5pSfqc0o8@aiOXY8@x3KEMg5bbBK8Iy619XLip1CHzjUoVD3qAEcHyrQEDV0WjjT5ec69cUlXyMxIK0s/QQnnUSqXFAg7ryd4WdkiDrEis5d1nKxjHzzqOn@HDROabPdSFlqxh/qUoY5juybqWZfLBRmc9UMGubHWB5U1k4yYEU41vdhT8weXwABaPw@3YwgTw9tOPbyzN@zorKEX379l6J9rKa6lUqj7k9Oppqpvqpao3cJ8OFD2tfjjHsrkzpZPKFtrzUy1Wn0jBQP3mKt0OeSqxzmwknw0zZ6McI4dvhp7b0CxxFl5EMqFMSghcS6dFKRzLXEvXhphSxAQ76Q@uOmJ11OZ0Q74oXZaqCzbfuGp2r/rSbavVj6k1ZlS9TXevZuJVvKVOmo1EwbgSm5mSOSj1zTE3L8da0cZUNdLNerp3Pi9MB7NCVLuRI5krMdaURmdTYR4ZCWcN5nZS70VrZ/NBght25qmM0bmJeTzsTSbdjZ8JnVvpvJa56HT1SDsyqCX40GR4Lo3mvYsz9anYz9QmgmfUzxeiE0atFCZTMdwatJUz9bbabLaz6cp0wBm3o04/3Locm@24Hg2Fximx1w9HCmNTjxfTqYuYmU0VmnnlumnezpvxCmOemfVY41xIKJ5J2RRC42yDNQLN2bl8UZtGz4J17Uw9Vwr9yuB0fFpRRuNBNiyX68Ow3r3Ot7Vg8OyqNjm7KTJ6@Lx1E6/2g/GsMBPYi4imDUP1RKmoX87G6aey2MoItbTYjgbSkesc178sz4XypFittiqjVmMYMy445TYf6DPla6GWSg/yxWGcq5fmhfhpoTbOZAqzSTsodbXUuNMKXV5Hp8WSWGhdsaEzfmxeeuRMWWH75@fGvNm4KFyXjFvo1pfncliaz9LNtC49ZTPGZbXIlvRBrxbuq51RMyZnNOG8UgibhUHqbNq6TRTSA1GqtAfaoN5SWmNTzvbZPDPPDK4abXGalxdTPhcuNq/Yfq4qmLFUN1Rj@5LUHihlY9E9LS66tXG720mUTwNZ8emik25GqrkRd5k3wiV1ztzU05K8qF5J3KCSOCvctnMp@VKNZCriqHJ6NpkFgzeyVJlGFtzsup8PyzMhHCiW09eXnqvzYNVT9KTTFS1U7jLBbP601Y1ceLS8uGCLEv8Uy3j08Tg8y47x2@vFhqrow4gSiOfrnl7M0FuJy8tp2yhcVzMtQVnEby8Hg@htlbmeFAxND8bP86kEWxkE9FO@XyrcxmQ1H56mT5VcotBaNOJmrjhW4mfFbva8qmfrQ@E6kevW5vNBN34uVoqDFCPGs9Vqv91ttmc3NaMyD1yGhX7bkzvNlZ660I@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@vqlwnG5e5Hq9k@ufz8ChRDKajbHNaPbvq13tqScmkWjMpHRLq2jTW4iW1IS6iMfYy4On3EudqKhCuRJmGmTUbxfw05FEvCpfBynwuXLf5cYiXnm4Mj3Cz6C3KTZHXlF7xqcrVm@NiRu73m9G0UA@U07XAeGFM@VGxwiSyFZXLFmeT/LRXawWMUfZsFG/PSp1MpSK2R53QSGqXUzMpMGm1bq@uGmV1eH01PKvG2uVFh@9HmqZUjZZnJvMEJk9zUmzk27OsZEj96uRJPZ2Nr5tsuHE6LDY6E08/cXszCcnX5UCxlG5K/Lhw1Y2ZjdJsdHmuSAo7DJa7LDNtVBYLU0xpudL08mYmNReLlJw2nrjZBcsXTwvZa9OTyOVT2XK9xutKuXxazKb44fRyWryOecRF7bITkQdPt0xFVZWgfltTYulAyAg2ItlFRuifBsan6WH9vJ7gRlzjrHl5ecH1FGEoxG7K2WjrUmilUucX83OJb1Yqo8pFo86UPer17W2dLdeVYkIqFqp1LVKY6JetVoyfaqkrPlAID9vT4iw9vRyPW8PEuefGFPmQthBFrjpViqx4BrITZ8TxpJIpVYx58GnRf@pOstp1M5EanUZTmbnUmYiTRSCVnXhYIz@bdqLyKB6s38xOpRvhstu9qKZ7odFkVI9mIsx5QrpUm@1M7zIxFy/Ois382BRrnXZY9hiBUb9@lWoYDWEunwrR3qRh3CjQ@aRRpJ7OJAzlNhu/0GVPIC6kGaF1yVfYYi9yXTrvaNPM7LI5z8KUI85JlUBEm6vNcXygnl0Y6YvW00U83m20zwZQ8Lh32xPkhifdaYtXklJibq8vmoNcZdxk@1fXl7FK48wTX4T00ydB653yiXl9UQ4ERCnRnRTGs9CoKMRP4xdlQTmflaoNSexGa8Er5VRdMFk11gukJG46maqsZx5Jx3NdKd0oqXq2IZzFRK3Cs@ysdWuWW9fxi@Bp4CpQG04DQeNyygakG1We35RuboIdJj0xLkatGjfJec7M1E2tXxVOFbbUqhYW2ryYCxqNVCkjXYyn81FxLuuhW6F4mlEqgsyBWRKJdut6Y7BIT9pMS5oVM@l47DZ4BhJkGEpiehPmRcEYdWd9tng5PlNm/fGgqXuGM7bqub2ZRRK9Zs9ghWKxXipMc3pEOzf6KhONCsGzlj6KGdWn4byQMbO9ZkMJZxLNbrt8dsNe1qWLxFWmdhsTIxW28CQmWrVoQChGWgLLVbXhxIQRSegOmOI80NEFRdT52Lj8FMmNx57OfDI2PaPb2OlFvNUdZLiJwHtCqbb2xM@a50pALsXErlFuTSfX@RZYiGpz0lCZ/G1jFLqQz6TaWbN8OeAqqerCZNOJlnAd7t7onKRKk2rIjJwXxG5MkLK520E/e1Z4KgRupKfAlFP0q6tQ/oxjYpInbWodhW1eja7URZAXUzfl@OW0s8gMeyVJPCsEs/pNNdqpXfBKDoZR@akYGDXzp8XbTlvpsZKmlmvVQIC5jQZzrevqEzfpXFUWdW12pnfPUxUldC0VVK1y3eSyVzpbiqXzV5l@9TYzj0crutIW6914XR16TkOawKfUYpSJiRMx3WyxDVEOcbHZos0PRJa7bQ0G8TN2ETUWbEo1pv14d5Fonw651m1JO63PB@zpcHZbSV9zY9HDcRVhxFyZi0rk9LTluZifNgpdpVGQBJYfzvvGWXosnk/bV9GUJz4K1D25TrM3K1a6o1aOjbXbca4WCrXC5lOnMjeuSkwzWzwLxbJzcyblBuPSLH42SkVr81njKhwe3PZn5XgtWo3MuIk2yKVH@W6E1a6NmDqrn3XzaTEnXUrG5aItDJnoYlwq5OM5T0Tkbyo3twEpxz7VOorZ60r1i@tQLcoKkbNyZXp7m02xw5jUzxWUUxgTp/zlbF7r3wzaV2UjJDNa@cZTiC6ii9rtVamjVlrnl732tBuLVfSzZj8xXtyMqnLVM1o0Cm3tNFsZKtnFNQhctJqI9BtKrtGSr7PVQJkxo63UFGxwLl2U5122EAlcSGrgfDY8TVwPW9HBzaCZmVRvZoN@tBaLaGNxETNbT5Gx2IjdnA9rrNC@mfY8wVNGqy3m17mrsF4sTUdFs6KJF4F4sHg7aAxz44ZnmLnIt81MKzBqB1vF6diTiYBVEL9sJoKl9kU/XRicXhlnV8EEU8/L83G8fxo99VRgMBn3jXK8qQSVCdtileZ0Ig6GAb6U5Zv6rN3IFzulTjDOjjxybGpeRJ/Obyq3vDkKqyxjzKOdKe85y4EFkZVvIjVP0xwFhjAXCVxPQhdqNxQ01OtaTTAzWmzQCCXEcF5vqlpzpvWbQfnqNDaYCvJFn0mLi05YaVRbndJsMe0kBuEOX5s0UvlrtRXKqKPezNC5aOIi2OSfKkM9VDZHlWJDSKtXQ56Xpp6Zks5e6rUJ0@mWUp1W/mksTZrhciqcml93AuHx7aTPqYvr3E2wX2mnetK02govqtNQunPKqdWhPBrqQTZQb6q5QXzWOBMvmPNFTpz34lfpSjPcuOgnBiGlO6hVAvNBWZaE21tjzBVuusUrrlOINNNXicGZZKTEWCMhnffZWaldvo1mOmI4wHh6hSEbzBSF0Hnu2mOeC0rkSV5wJXORkNR5qSG3a91JalTs9BvjUvqMTXPByemsPAydVdnQmE8P49kL/UZXGDEXSc0a5cuo0btNmc2wVglO4qPbity9DnYqPV4YBqJx0MGXnfbtvJGqpqfFm9JZzUip3YXo0acX6mkhn0@rzJnUKj0ZT7wmjVPhRrl4c/V0ldK79UjbNArc7Elk53O1fJ4RhPlNqmAMSs3zmlqIBYad9GXsqtcpqg2tIocuGCERG1zHWLUmnI8DYriSCuefmqfCU2ESrWoD1RTquVvOLFVB2RUijfLoZjpcZHoBaRYK566NcrczuoXe2l8wwfFZ9aZTlfrqbFo9N5sXoWGNGzSnyiCq8iNPOJcol3muG8JJWORaU4eactE1r2ulyYXOsr1FdCyOTsULmSkGR91UoRo9D/KnpzfZRIMbPhXFYPwyPE5Ng@XqpUeNiKNsoTtUAplBtS9eyTBlaEUr/fNArSQ3urfjzHViXmMWN20poZ63ptpFZjDNDib9emMWgulVvVk0jFr12uwUJsH2eUxpl3udejafuRIyPG/EymomVx6Mxs32cHoWjjD9fOi6fxk7l7vRQawgzm8uxqNE5XxRyPTOwp4b9Txu3vCm8lRW@k@ltmm2n2Jys3Z1zrbSMUENPM1j5nWvxRrMWXyYOw2LsUWhx8Ua6nAyHnfKVVUrzCtXl8DmWDBUP22zqVHrqmI2O2eicH3WAEv/XBMLtevzUe30@qwz7qiMEgLxzbD6xWnRyF9nB7fctFCdt2XOMyhfTMuRWERKtD2TyLDUG2cjkVZseF6a5LMjPTq7BK3frcwrRbFaumS44eVNbuA5lzgurl8umpNwNSVeR9uXU2kajmRTM7UXjzcCs6vzU@Eq3h4VpsPGOde9Yqe3iYEx5Bt8NSVoUplJP41C8@zMzAUiuYvo2fWV2I9OO7lxsJCa1lqFqJkoSa1W@GlanQ7EUp6T6rPJNFjJl69MNRyZNa9uBxfQChFG6M6ucjHxMix2AvLiNqPntbba4FMB9pwNThvNK4/WVZ9KomdQCeZDo2guMKvwMDO@TY/PO9F2o6@0TtNniR7TCQs5T92IFm6jT9dPl7J@3ffEhqBy4lJ1cnUJJknbbNTDsyspccMtmpl4i2/nF1zugk2Fz87GiUIweF5MFG8YoxYZgrQ8TYPX51kleFVp1sNjT7aUnXV6tdtGNTO9jN/ecMNKqzY5x8lYiA1MpXK/2piX8rOGLEZzg2pOSjOewtXUKCdGUjXbzOlspSPlw/3B2Wn@VBxfCONZTvUEuoXGfPI0Horx80uFF3U1XzV7KSF0Ex@EZkJhlHq6aDLzMz53zmXizbg@kIXzfqlh9I1JayTJqfBTZOYxq/2KfBHJVuvXar/RK5V0IXMZjBlidlAbRm8b/Vl7IuY654xkJiaCMjstRU01Pc/L143Lq/NOLTAXKvHzUl6fBdps/qkWmJhsI16r1Lvtki4X@zBwem4amhZXQKWYPe2K4Ue9QmDaTF104l0jcxqIF89n5YZc8gSuctV@NmhMdA/bG5aD2YWWOw9J01i3enUxDOiZSafnuajE2Nt@WpuWmIjZCbV4Y5CoStzNTZMd5aoLw7iMN9qeiyuFFavB21j6bMHV26FRZ9y7id8MTydPNzeXT@1m7Qya89ojRmuXT0z36uLMiEkJges00pliSpuMAuf6sCqFh0XtphG8kTw3s2xh@hS8COT7hTZXKvUWi7RwrrfUeHbYvszw834j3mRCuXKgcxsSR@eN7NNNvjfuC5niTAhda2eG5zpcmo1P9XgsyoUTE94INYfDpieeUmRPLNSb94Lp3CSaZTt6tcXkyp5MS9OgF1Rvo3yJNcKdkmIajVi9lktUM/nMWfEidy0VE7UCf33tubkqZHKpevT8ojcIX9xwRppNX/b6tSDTL2YGHdY042O5JueN3KmenfVuB1fDcXsamxSNm4V6wY/l7pCT@NGgVVRj0dRV8ylSDoRyl2zudqGowVhklmA6gtQ5Z5Xq4LoVl3Nn7I3Sgwl0FuR/cH051gVJN3qJFtT8cqHGMo1yt6mfKb0KUKi0xyNBGibkQU8M3TJVthbPx1rKhSSUb6rD2E1bvq6fh2LSeAbz15vs4kLKstDqjZtabxy4jubAdA2Hnwqt3vBqUmoa1Ui2WS9WwkzzqZqVuEKuWGzemh2uVA508xOzEYuf5ThhmB6UcvN0O12Y5oVG68zT9wTrHWGSb6aUXLPDG7P5bSAR0FNSn4n2o5dpKcuZ00hT0sOZ8145xCsFbVY@j4@G1cp5MH2eu5K0gR5IX6WWR7Q5TwzlyLwrpVKnzcJNpsukrjLZfrApGUJV9UwLFCydV/jf/@StQkRdVykYM9HkDn6uyRDtbS6O3tl4gu48ga@3b@07gc4@mxsJSPb71UALlON1NPAN4UOrEPps04@f8sBHi0cvny36uOV2AvSC@3iQA/r5DmnrQahDx8wrMj7I6nsE0Cee9AkKPgejryf/zDiEH9DgXaIENtE36lyUN@4v0kY5gvt84D6ggYejjUeeLm6TGiQQmoxXJeCn1/Ez3FXhW8hIHwHnynn3rsf6gaOt/ECcMVLpTiMOn99Bs9q7YiCmbRRWa2L8am8Ghm7Isnyw9s7HyXiWiweiCbq/B1G9pnd4l3jwHghJBxFNmVeHxlifdgZdrTeRiEJG/fZMmC@eCImECW5zFPzW2iOUiyZZukFzDM5xkqB7Ou8vt@ikW9Ljjl50c0bcEdRJyGo/q6MPxE0DXjwdOo5eSSk5GC6l0NrkY3gXfUiqycDR8E59OFI9HrfpSZoezuPCiG8599FobHsi3pkP9K199oBcLl@tx093oO@vJpGKpgo9zWkQ@nH2zXdO6M5lyw405Eeb/WkiCqamb8ZIKE/8cKsjvo7Cp8T8i5yytoQz5yMRH92tdiVQNJBfPH0zjoaPXqdjDb/5BrfQOLJ9JzYr8JkZjduKLBwy31B@4iNwfJ3@8NDeFEYgKLfffEPjZCvSooXIhguTj5apgjaa25llC@RxWZfjDZQnLny26vZ@DeQSqg0y@YgfWtMBzAKx2LsFTgA1fTTqtqjCcFFUV89BcR8f9xHuckI@LNOWO/4gPMoN3Xfn0SQy3aUHLsfEBqV7YBC3veMEjb2T8aU36kpw4rSSvumPhyP6/Nlv0WtzBL8i@zjiZX2V02@M8SvyLsIhM@Ql0dgCGHjGnd8mvCluNs2yLdDxjb58hfVBfBX6KSAgWODxE9igG/HlA8TX0Wieb6zPFLuIqVmOlRYZdl5aDbfd1MA43D7dOXIeEuoHdwRR9JHo0UZqH1Kxrm8kDyF5yJu9N5J7iHtsvJWsQzJ@vPiNZBmSrXcid6drkG496X8DwEQvTxDXR1N7NHlZcVkbeuBWIM@WwnYRj2fJ2JUIEKthrPbYzk/srVHIB6t1LGHbEi/on1SsLAAUaZfdefB@LS00FXeXd1lysVGmxRPymXyxMNs5Elj8SEsCtYvluw@28JMNAqD/gSolr9OXhVutvarolvz4YdjpYmsDs0Lkhx/eo8wWxG354x6W0me1EPrhbtTQ4tYaj/Vt1XW7WpkWdqbdeeytYza129JHYl2PZacMrlWI1bfW/VqS1Q6UAYg/bEajy5ObfFzH3BkP5HClPdZ8tLrFl/kYfCU96BFFe6SXtNdB4eu5yqPcQ04eRuT2WlngPmH80St2Gito3/9X3NWutZEj69/pq1CaJNhJ@4skZ@dgYGLAEO/ytbZJhocwxNgN9MR2e9024M3wY8@PcwPnAs7F7YXMqbdKUnf7A5jZ8zw7eQZ3t6RSqVQqlUpSVTr3BuW21Jzis3aKZ/Qo/b2NfVprlgg/HtRMm7II2japhhsawTnotaRfkzJBgL1YXpXviAQbpIEFC4CJP71zAjBaIxwwsxkxbubEoJ@XO6kk54sr7zw@Yi5Z7mMyGWH1FDr9PwwuEE5P2WMEx0uLJDWHNDPZbbtBr43pITfVPJH08xt3Kpeal39cBo5qlp@Y636kWXJVFZV13FRW94/LoT9Gme9x96X0nSizWFaYTjec@BQWvF9A6EeZLN2ElTOVojhQYMnwyJTETgjnT0rx0fpz88Ucu5SxvVADA1bldDpwFoAmgRTlZClP61wbsejU3hfPR0a58WItDDFphStIZS87SXGO5dwOT97Jr9Z1FFMkmYKb7NAwhwaz4NLotqQGm3L59jm6WYgMetKYvgrDTsYoTFphYAjGQwdl8sSdlVWrRL2Mq6fqtNKrrrSXDzPvlunLc/2J5xX6AOVT8yaQeH3Fw6aMYZPQb4KIQyZzOmYjqsrcPsBhRZE@anX6O3JbFejZ3EJG4sMnGXuu1HKeZ@KUeHC3Wn0cDEV3yNJ6zcV32xHIs0EL7di/JffB/Rwrg/jw1N4tvyeXLkE5yEMntp1uTkFmyxabtTUX1ViGv/9t6XlhHA0LF0G/4PdvSKm@mDhLyu9LcL9VNR5d5n7AQeFKffeTliZ8LpsPIRKbUE@htnzfv80gD2nO8CLqZh3xSceHFksOPBDzufGuf9MhrV88tgzC6I7/TmixUMyPB6OQU3RF7LtO/Rr8GvtTLfItIr1i0OisMZw4Twb3C@TrRM5K5kqiIJXgXTmbAHGKkixw3S@ui/4Dovo86emZE@X9VvsaSID3fpXlFHUXc/K9E5muh681kAKXV@ixK14mBnx2FFWwdhJN@J2aj/cSHuQLH3EF3@t1isMHgpHSDcMBmBxHQVF@jQgghH/WaG5X6/W8DowkJ9Zxyl3OMeOKIDus47AM9hgvTqvDXaB0yjM0FrClvvUYOMtfphGq1WTCULgFOYVW8EcoLciV@G2mGTZ/VrIzSfi6k36LQMui9uoxID0KtIuLZRLFcqaYyZwgxbNHqdFqt@EIYt/vhYTxlt/tEtJCi2cxOfAIipj639j6o1PUeWaRl/TcTHoulZ6XdEEqzpVvXw/jTKvJTO7S9zjfvXLjbN5MXeuKGl07YO9S@XCYwLv8UN4oT4u0IM68YbtSuNImrKUScomUn@f0vqQ8T5WxDG7TTyVd8/eK7nmLZSrvh3T9@HV0B/nsg0FfWZzi0nw/6P4o5kebwhJWwa2SFEd/M9vJoNQGES1OciQmiIl52G6sx1DelIzE4THjbqx9cPPaJPVjZhoNies3M7DmjJEElbjON0y4O55JqB5Ofp4AwTDBaMqM3A1TeKILTxJgkeu5qdYxnkLTA5yaNj3E13Gs@1f8MYM9jZzJtzQ/8ZlgfieNl5sWaQKx0H3uzidTWpqMhmNfPupGPTCLxHVPpiHOFxIHIVag7WtIClunL/dBLsNxv/PcyomkoDCSYobuNkVTOs5QMuy7qAuReO/8Vnjt7LZ6pBV2/TtVgU7dYp/8TuqyzciPRhGNAZ8aOFTReDDoBtqvm7rl6xw6INDKe1xGiCEmlIa8U8MFUcnv4UlfjqFCeXUIyLe4ZxgnROMrREyHJRjBv0m0XgYEcpR3Kv0JeyZmN2grcuXFV2P4cYUA7tKyL4GE9JyMHrY8QEvLO@ZikTT1UsZ3f0QqEDU8ZJ@HcLW66jh/HQftb1u7aqVY/FOp@LaUIJkxVRfzb9@pWkJFMgkrxVKx@L70znG2wsFErjZm2lnAepcDQE/tYaL/RLzp3yA4t1OhGYMzRqT6R/7wxu/kHafud9gGfDFmioCVxyBX3/h5xRfSreDvntTdXuQpWnZdQ7zgF/Oz@K5ts2MNz8EdooE/7AUjuWkU3gQdENDcm7oMu93wlg3RuLIk9EChnj8iorzOqjRK7JdW48K6C7uLJWogugM78LsIb9iPtCYD6akB3O/zBSAHThQBIVlZvzOFCdXX7raCHthpDgLwshRTwCBATeuM2/6DODiMxO/EQemGdcL2GJ55W6ZnCiT9Qh4rNNz9YUDSNyYw9woXS@BOHdz8WGuoxuFO83OlXlX0fFQ//FTbrm6rzRPV/FhVW4dHJxwETH083CPp0lCVg236etCs1zaPm4f0wa00qKTLCU7l4ERVfzqqVxsNdVhXtf2jvRpBI/D1ykGzVm14qnawtXdMk/WupwiCOjhsqr3afq1J2ZqHHtdqijlxOXW4o/ar9a2P9FrZrO3Vmidc406teYDKdqi2ijqq1Ju1reO9Sl0dHdePDhtVhYY527XG1l6ltl/dzlP9VKeqfqoeNFXjY2Vvb6qhh58PqnUgn2rlZpWwrGzuVbkmbud2rV7daqJB8dMWEY8Q3PNU46i6VcND9acqNadSP/E00Eb1r8eUiRLVdmW/skuNczKPUIX6Zeu4Xt0H0kSJxvFmo1lrHjeravfwcJtp3ajWP9W2qo2ycvYOG0yw40bVUwjmylUTDKIWpdPz5nGjxnSrHTRpzjg@atYOD7LUyZ@JMIRlhYpuM4EPD6S1RKTD@gmggg7cAZ76/LFK3@ugKVOrAio0iGpbzWQ2qpCI2Ew2Ux1Ud/dqu9WDrSqSDwHmc61RzVKH1RrIQDBR7@cKVXrMrUY/EV7ySMzqGM71uDtVbUdVtj/VgLnOTRzQqGluYbJtfdQ0p7FccOZuuT24gTe7y6dNIQ87id863K6SxifRYdz4@zFNOj@kN@9SaTTR2ER61bugPFedd/yL8dV50L8MsTS3xWQHuxddeYinlEUA3i/OA1HC9UY5F1haOj//VDmndW7j/DzrPaVkCo3HSmgvrA/lyuo2dsNWh5f5KdtSklAbr7Svd08cLydtLa@s8SGrCoWOr4vh8iIAGzORDkpAwDqQjHyrsdVXiSp5izltK@KIGdPGIrO9GUb0p/9r/CJzQ@IDCWc5t1AoYA3LaCDyibL4UyUcFERHBuFzAMElV5mPfP/bVaaYrA5Lfm2gypoynHdEy8CrTPaR4hf@1VTx3HR5RhZ3TVlZMe7gjZt2MGbIb5pkSvdLfsgty4hpj3@yBhuuiJTCrFTFF1n16ZPMKykO/6JiK8yWrStxDgeyX/mp9hmLueLKu/LU94/2u4wt3DpHbBua70653Bn/fDyTDDTAAiy/iCTBRLZUC4VEGdLKWJ@0meGr/hqZboMOzamYqq99ntbhIV/cBSfL02Q8DO6S2JMY3q1X9jePd3ZIcgLbdz@8/9N/lB3tcX84@smT3xPUg0iZTF3Som8DUtM4KTFKtkjv2ZkJlpOI7oPeQ0ZEmjSdxh9bpNJaz5miI0h8DTEDobkRIgz0EWTDRZCAoatwP99/7hh@nTsyNQNkUk3NojW91h1r@C1SlZgH2uIlszvhXrvDH8C2w98McdsgzUCaxfzeYDQhzqXFBcs9d8c4HOC1DV8rRpa8a/h40DJnkIQwkJnshQF38PlN83aiF0mvRUdjvHK3c0lC4vk0FiZIC4dcoiqOwsiMYPkY0JefNL/R44kODoQkhHqojBpExh1bMmeC94jNWQ8MDflsY5266NUrW9OagiE1q5ES@386dExyNDAqcqBBTQE2J48snW0KG6E/LGfVd@FUePUGnLLmWP1OnDuvORpK2bhE1@8mgowSWHFAGf50a@twTJYTk8WSM0Wmf4keDP/fSJM58NdowUnQY2qxHA76Y/@JlGSoQitavTJRgltzYixxTC2mZvLTSQzmPtkx17Zh@hjenWwsEQl070zMhxMJKZaZQwAwOewayfELB748iK9btHL6wGP3mez0D/vt3iBjAnKZqWIG7pnHOpdnjsjhJStb@EWVqG4P8VU@sJ9HlhlYcJEUu5iol5ErMN6UWOag0YXXbPSwo5xZE2QomREes1NRDy0z@O/0CaN4lumY1HtSRRcH@7LbIYgplBL4ZgfECBA@@5RssCYb1bkBROe2G55e2Mqv9CyOKJckAnleVk12zxG1LnnNjKlI@9KA0w5UCTgvOzpm04U/usV00RXo7EMkhqYyL9mNCSrRtkirRhjhm80T1XmSvbXYs5kS/GqxP@5/6yPIsi8mLpMjn4oAlXTBmlf7LQ4G1X1au9248jcg60a6/lqf/aq0Zb8SpjleuVMtWOm/jGKKkMZ5C@2S5qGYSq32N3x0DY8Gt7ngjn64rpxuuYlpRGsGjlg3T@m/X7ggAK9MnYFV7pe@NSKtykS2/tKoL3iSsWufTvCk7czr1ChCjr7gwKxWg4Ay9CYc0pwdbYxfyq0ODp@ukuZ0e5u/aI17rf5lqxd0J3zq9Jfwul@I@uNokB9MHNd109ZAOAKHixTCfeSrz0G/E95GapOGAwxJjYPjxlHa8JewfG2J5UupP1MdapNrdmbAX8JnUhRejqhr/LKa6Ijlw9jcw3ZCbWlhs9YEH@CYasgMRPX2rGa8e3Csdv2@PyR98IjPXKq9oO33SXyQMsWnMKNrkTTIvoPaG7p2tQPdhS07ZeUHbNSxtj1HV6CheWCtDA1FQniowyrCNj8hVk/YBPOzDY7b1TFGpetwoL0BwWgKZVNMnJfjrucgduPnWvMjFuOyMGfbDE1rxtYHW6KoTj0x1lJjhq3@aEJEcaaNN4T2Y7abvGJnQATRWUxOXtT1EKS9A7NfN6KmIty8lgI8g9BQ9YMbBItjM9xT@ojP2WqzWUy3svav6En4OiM6Ur3nxL3nIWZo3lPv/1M1ffCuOuq22rTCUo0xir99S3rgZhiNkHW/olRxpVQq5UpvYaI9blTyPBDwv4kg5ji1/aPDepMIqV3kG8awcyaIz0G75DQWkSOH0F3U@q8QyCY/ScyVr0w8qODGj69blh0Ld9Wlvm@3YO6lFkZpdZhNsjDJh0MOHAZvUMRCqeFItcLpAUL0sZBETQnoHocu08HHZGqxeLI3Py7wFbh1ia@62A/9yoX5GwkA/46/Uakhrww62u099UnP71nsg5GZ3VuSwZmOeWYJJrZUYo5lbxlaElEvm4TT8XFGIkL0gF500x6SbGndEMvhCItxiUU8w7Ipa1vTugi6AY0Bwqt9HWLCEXFlOoJNEMmIaA73uI21gwmJcZkTrYBGVyfs2ayCleNYZ3D6@yCatEO1dEXLbKy0ooHvdzhSwnggoQCQnqdR3qWZQ9zErcYxApylIp@bHJKwQUgWkn3jLnzHwtffhfS5Y1pDXGXcCzavsawXQNSixogHKSK2ZeassD2Ffd4sd3uLGAJlsyDEAkd/BGLgYVOKsKL@ZobgJ2YXD@6outzf034AUZCDEUWDdAJgya6un04w4NF2/TiTQZh03SIw5WLQICN@suQ5ZQNLv6C9OHcKp2kZaSM1bpK1xNwJEEJTbAOhugrxF5nzhmKyR@jzHuGM48I7uOQleNM5S7M5KZcNIJLIuTIHZm4uzLfzYeY0TL1ZWevfsMM2lGK2kFaIN@iQ5CMIETd/NzSil93KdUPZYLKtv@qGF4jbRJKCasPPxIs7NvmZV2ApQidTxYlgOt7UmmmSRl3fbTK6i1qj8eFvqDVjsdj40peO0gnrMpbYZ5niuYuHEz/ijx5R/OimgldB65iKXgX05CvJboB1NUj9xV1V8cjESZxkfl1zukgvVaQ0VUQjly5ykSqy4sSeSqd6FyUg@vGbbpnRS/hUEveAWrcdVHR6rTtZ3RTZAR2baRAyMuURb@VMMwgynraV9WmH7GdO7KI5tW0vdZhXPoLHJ77dFy6HvCqm4x3cmaN7LAY4Vyp9wm7A@xndoKwmA79Y989Zg4xu1xoX6ScklW2wJDipZg9xVyuTrCW7qpYGLdk1RK4IE1uy6lOmAXbpXfr3WmV0BbkkspIJbnW1KCTCs@vlU1rKSrcYOVh04pmZ3xICjnrQEfnNR8ZkGshkUuPKSG4LUx5nZDeBwncBxzU54v8zIr1OvmJGSYiGBhQ@hDHVSp5/R8sz3mNmEDz/WIu1/ig@ja300MifxjWfmVkj3YqFuaenknl5ErOKpcJDmQ2xLZ0WZl482zDpYEOAvJPsCdLtwUisSWem4OVISMZaSjBiZ6dhOxAJlSZbQuhKWW@OAE53uUHOm2qVk3Blrls4PY04qZkzxSSZxBvCtKuXEshOAGWdVCnQf1GH47hjcmAvzFeSfLrbF3GEhWX6/SG2sJlNvz/EFpI50e0Ps4WJZWhJy@Wn@SLVE0ICHErUKwa2KSVlkEm4S@a6m8rFCE3Okr7M/W5mDrYJqaptnc6MqmRJpEOXpOvgnzvpmCXtaDTFjkS8U9sbZ3FraY5rf/M71iOzbr1dIm246SlBenM6EAEabWrgPjrLImS2LUASW4xges3ck7Ob7NF@WRYsvAZF1K6r6/Tt3hRYM6sUs7MKpfHeHyO/Nhf53GwUhXiJtTobH96eLtNY48BTOOwgt@vM2fF1HsHqTQKrdOsSPZQm8QJIuSdByj0BUiEBSQ/stzRf8uPSEHHq/MdAfPkyC4N/fqaFlIZBkrYTwIiNdfBta/IYzOekbC3xmbqWnCqzBWI9@TEYP07D4Lig13Y3Tn@8bsHq9nd/GE5H5VhI2TSvzMHIYrU0i5YHtFhq83pX5zOqEq9t898urgO7Elh6vKfFj7EujKPE13YTaCntVd8Ci8d/aQH9vES3pseDIJ4yw5C27PzO4ZAHIcTCJFfFbIGEIEuvQ3VCmhAPp04LP16tTns/RsDThcWyj7bkgxh8EkanEjVNJFaK48wSLhZOZrYy8m3e8uzR@pfm1j8IB6TjXM5FgPP3YMcXo9SUSI9V06ml9ZPmsrnz2Wy7knrbVGySpw/yVzNNX6Gm42I6Deq@f6tn/4cg67aYHvgDmvyp4ZEFSL6ciyQ22lvauKX6496FP3SeMtSlRB4/skZazLmOs7SkKm1aMmvP@LCKtTl8n6@rhBoMRojUeID9mkgOd2Jww0bmCwNP5@2Et33OnXdRBdtoe36rr13l6wnzaoj9C5vXQ/hOXO7iGoJ@mwgd@Qnz51eJSd3xdQpOJD9A1vL8vgdXo06NhRfXpNESXTMzSa9p5esCBcdqNZxrdVpRMbyDzdDXoplrfYkU8@x8E9hTtKeHFCJi4kVV6gXvFOiHeXR1MTHHA0tK2zVPIOU8dctauZ@gbk2eqm79Gyg53aFO4llrD3qCXX1UqE0v8p3fCgUbmLE3x3XLp@bOTsrhycXErAp6/vB9sViEE5yLVsS7FilvONglDsJCOncBNvHC4PbPw08XBRTFpgUiE6yazUw/CrskaqJ8OLySaBTAgbIiN7YmwCfYmhjTfJMI9wB7Th@3cn6JJKd44OkoPsYZ2MPtn5rMfAwSxPNX1Vc0EO37qi7HfTGi37ZkyaChmPNmVBpq6I1rjskRefDhEh517JE0BsbrZn1rARsf6xvfnWe8By7XBTlcfPZ7fA3R/eh3u6GnPofDbue5K7dD0wV2dpIFipIFRwll8EQcvthT/k3QTYRwRhbgFnb9fDe8YnDYAdfXFvku09AfYCctg3ms7l9V7wYZ9/RnlxiTmvwGzXyj3DNc77lyaYpyeQv9cbASMIPQflLuXmuQaTOdpjPTHKjvUsVPhNHbkqcacjoY9pQtajIOc2RSWbLiF0Zo9nhuEHU@uvlfwqCfoaYj2cF1Ob76zd3LLVmQ3RLX/XJXugQNiwJD44QQPU8rcV@G06k//h@s27Ac4HIj23jtldiEv7FkO4wxHiNL3YwuL2l4iSV@w7gaM@BYVOZKfEoBpNEdO/T/hlgFmeXLaFkCrOCoTWPSb6cQOV0589TyeHT5wzJB@Jfa6JgRqIcf0RPHJv6So2G9M@Y43rE8YzMcDlDMyh0UOEcBx3nZXv/bbaZSqagXgzdvVKWySQ@5nKpsVtQ2Pmxuqm1638T7q/WV9@/LcnJuO/udPm6aj/dqk2DwFPSGFgLb9Epp61hRYSmFLn5RWH/hlV@cr69tlKPCaWXzrFC4oqd//uO///lf/1Oo6Jf/xcsmv5z@bDPl8/nCi/b3F6/uy3g/3T5bfnFx@mJwtnxVBpf9Hw)

[Black interp](http://nethack4.org/mirrors/blak.tar.gz) cmd line: `blak -e0 -t1 polyglot` (no debug, tab = 1 space). The last of `<>^v` chars
is IP starting point in corresponding direction. Chars `<>^v` are replaced with spaces in the interp used. Pushing digit prints it.

The program is on line 156, spaces on line 155 are also important:

[image]

Main program is pink, significant spaces are yellow, significant non-space is green. The `>` must be the last of `<>^v` chars in the program.
When `5` is pushed second time it collides with `*` and program terminates. Spaces on line 155 are needed to prevent IP from turning.

Answer (score 6):

## 153. [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20060708073949/http://electrod.ifreepages.com/l33tspec.htm), 6977 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(3 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S / \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz (  coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! 
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@          /"78"oo@    h#115 o# do            x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRc -BkBkBkLzLzLzMbMbMbxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================   x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++              L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                                    _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----._>]|
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n114O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39; 999;
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*9 9[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9 111<e$P+x+x+x+x+x*D*x+x+x+1+x+1E!s
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} 9

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6027""ing-?"ye h m 3 ;p se
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591 ,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main( ){q(z+=1,z)?puts("124"):y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! ");  main(   ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9                  @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclxx"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   _ @125iRE
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''         $>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/pppppppeeeeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*<s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001948

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tL1Zc/NKlhj4fOH5B/2SH6V7SYoLAO6URH0fV5EURVJcRS1XFwQBEiQIQAC46qqie2ai3Itjxi6XO8rddldV2xPTEeOHDs9MhB3dERMxfnX0j7j92DEx9Q9qTibATaL0fbfaA4lAIvPkyZMnT548uaLLGYPf/vYAX6iqyou@rJrIFAwT9XRpKuh@lFqgT5xkhANBisJQSb0/GQuKaRxTB4hFSFJ4qQfvyFRHgiItBR38AwhputrXuTEyB5yJBIPnNMFA6sTUJiZSxf3Rgghlx@pQ8uGYY0npA5gp6JoumCQ8hFBTkblxt8e9CAm/SFDTIdxAGUH@fvy9iXh1POaUngGQEYQylVS2lHyBIYrQpaobAsbDC4ahYs8YQvOswL8AjQMop0tqKVk@fxHEMugcSOc0WZgjrmuYOsebkqrgIBbVy8169WWMAGo1crmXvkF04VMVlJvwo50gUgZVXe1NeMwfcyBAMOapKMmCQfGQ9zOk2SXpxw50gHSB61lglKjqCEdB45GMJMRrGurK3MDPI1kC2BwTQwIuArSEcHlgoLk2BgyGOha26TCQIgg9ZGgCL4kST1JHwtwUFANya/iRBHTPJFlGPUGGCBuSeC8gQxNjy8siwE/1VArBxWsvMrB@OxQARhFWTBA0KAXMBBUXGnBkxYuZzmkaEAmMrAPhpjQG2ZNMp4EEzpCwdEMUQ1B6hH/aWu5VxCnbuURTiUMc0DvRCW5D0HFh@gleNBB0AVBya8lzzXTJBBZg9iZRVeB01NAFwb1bB3aShMRUnIKJM@InxXd66sxWck4oRiuGn9NM6kAPNq6KFIf8CXT4cAK/hMNxQmXLGfR0eIfdlshDUWu6i3OjxE@QQd/dCfCbs126rz9TgJUCrsiIVjWT5nwaEOgzgUCaw07s8k0Dfk3eShidviiLLeGyoHpQGqigoJaX5Iyf6Dqu1humciPItKwqfeAnZFafKJgfCoowUAS8CrXSi4QpcA3EnZSROiMcbgwkKDQDF8lWRbKUE2EoqCeQPZujq3QNVZ4QOIhpmFgAgSsQFWMsiKiFRE6ScRQIx6gsqnXBmMgmjjNRerjkQfkIPT9akcGrPQw0VqeQHAdIiQfUpfFWDSREATAUhEqyioN@@Od/3uv3AU@S51W9Z4trC/VUnqhRjhALuglhgVUVTiZkAZwXp25FhwSmnCz1OBMnryzsJAgRJNWZOpF7SIUE9ZkEVWvATaE6iqLAm4Il5Jbm9aIxN7L0hmRJLmR8zHWhYEkCJG2SbR/6lIZS4gXqgMiMbzwxxRjyaVnkNOhvXR@PXR8/3AlAnNvvPjqk6f4JCJz/iHjBm/M9yWkldzSjYXKGKvUobWEOVCWAfDxy8AlVExSXcweH0@vUu063H@szl/tESvB@UVJ6LifIeArSdbpP@AR/Kx3fn7yIvZ0iYJlhLLi2Ci7e7aBA45A6MaXHnKT4tQVq@WzXVphqPGCO42D/ljfmy0u/qeVxQBoeLJYqlg9QQ35DFgTNxfhZN9YSGG5vtnHAvoy@wGFn@Fi69zgPnJ7trBMMkNOdjOK62pBUrLVkbYDbFmCKYmigvXUsujwHwmNgJW5C6@9FXSLWRPODYiEqcSY4dQF1QY@uxIjUSKvG4fg@rCdtDJsatILbrdBCb6s@gy6AKm0ar5SyrM4gYUIbbr5Agyg4ca4PRQSRrQwlrQxZKRKf3ayNFNArGFtXQDFfV4K6gGsdqHZb9LfyCODBgAUD2Ky6sqWCxtwCsPBWk7ipN0gSoUqNQUvoC8QLWPWADhKsdgUnMiHV0AC7B1tAjC8QDu9WtVc1zdTppO8GdPWSfrdC4cxv1ymsb5AozJDMKf0J18emlwJROJ4XNNPWV5ATwwSN9LLZIZ4@uw31GwPq8NPLtElbYreuW2lgXW@Vnt0icljJ2MaXTwadijjbfEQ9SQftJC9epg4A0xeJO77DIDsEfOd4g4SVIQBCJswFfmKCcgNBng0kfgCyi6lTLPVotUUvkwev7dRBwfvEddKYGPbsmwDlp9demIw3Ufhwib7GA20sRnW240EKf9vjfcycMd6DWF2TCO3Blq@f5vwge5/BOVYVdQ9SYOQaLQbZDbHKAQyyOjYGof1aWV@ksq4txHURQZmB9oCaD/I3ME3NOIbmQjIHk64fJIVu6IuCWVGwsNCmvpBM1XJ3ZbUL6tmA@kmvUqD5SVeav8gQ8VuX4dCgpmCHiQZKQAP@OAGpczlFAxQn8U9j4K0gB1HgBIV1dwAgAfIDo1yiQVRyDpRKfaHwLoefVCU/VDqHFzlwxXW4wYFjrfmSVsdYC6E2sQ@wwZfSQXOJoK1s3U9UP7e3xVu3AcS8czr9Q1VSXE/ODx8@OI@dZ6DhP3z4CK5T7PqIXR5wfSQuH3FhOD92kRhe4sKhtyQG9rt3Pt@uMM/d97jY5rh1Wkqai7s9Pg7ee7lb1n4G8NMNqg40G0D78APwON2JBHa63Y6zGWTU3xV3c5/G2rnO65JmM6HITTnr3eZCkLBBGmuqju3YE9zYvs@TcUKH1hBsV37g0p13t8zd/d3TXc9z9@z04tjuEy7RhUxBeq6xv6@rE2g23behYx9773bfBqGx7CacjPPI5Yr5ZEiIc7u/jrk9nMVtl1MAre26u3MCU23@3PIDneCbewNu95pVQAduoME0dDn9TzFIv@u@d3ucENft9EJPI@F0Amd4zASDZBpLJmFQDgQwXS/t9PLGI1CPiDdkbFP4dMusgFf6yPLskcfacjpGBdKyKtBeAgnQXPbWPRxFVXzKhNjBxEhVtxMifTEMQfxw44EVo7QDgxGL0hwMfai4i5VFgxtgbNSkobenyoK/TWwMBwLJR7i@@veaNVWrXfDzxqYQwYABpyZzPNTMXXR3DnQHCEFQaXp/iPvkFeKXNg/pnXwuj9Ay8JyC@deTiPU9kYwBZi@YSLhLoIvAVWx6Q@MuEK4VEA@Ndh84Lcwl07LFQRDqOEqeM1xubP4lLfMJW224ycdErXrtpD1Weei3CND041CrE4iyylTSVQUz2Z8F1CCxJ7gMXiDfx14Qo2SyEMi8zd99yIFjr7zZLd5uY33JXN7gEa2ostpX0REAYNH0@23BhsrRGEwESuAHKnLcQRMSOEN0T5jSWCAdoKsHYAv5wN4QdNLakmg1SxX3SPNRE5Q@JcyJSihXMtmHarKRTzjoiaHTstSFpHvCwxiafFkwHHviL0fyKjo4a6pqJkhdwv5rIu1RIspUJ2Ak9ARZGktmgQyXyApuCTdafhWahnQ3CKqSYFK2@bppHPHIyUZxQT4IfGF7EEXU1fHaJDJsRh0GMWuEnYEw3E@wQ0M4dGIPg235R7H/GA9h@Xmqz/PIp1qva08bMIYB8bCWn9c0qu/xYEgyzLX2tCHjBCUe6vLr3ZXnE8s8Y//1ONeW4bmNcV/425HWyFmC3FAmhraVuSc2QPynpihizbn2DhLvkQ/QaHaR7hnes8EjGLandgV5Hgn5BFn0m/OlH1sjkRBlPZCv9xbEnrjUfLkvAmWCaeGbiy8COJ2yKGxA/S@pUNdLkkFGQ7eFglo3KneUY9Uy7jSAjk1IYNNT3d@9dmxjIaIP4jRSsTW2cT1AXzK8g2I8kl/HFEEnktsO6CuKXoeQ2Ma4K5LbHoBju8sGFQiPH2KWFPHoE@41qtBCCTMCRoxPggxYJSkcXSMPbIbuo2fXoN4hpiuIE1DeNFgH2P0ZMF88RiDFbld6CxT4gklfPfeA6ZPuPraBcA1e9bnQDuPNiW7KQs9@/tff70EBvC6eAbcgDdba8QB8w0XlE98sLTsqfiG3/SVLYIYTWeIIG4jrcyh5Do92cfLasR81VuDI5xtwOhTuYlW4IJz4BjX9HTmzKNcFedITVs/9iRAW7/bsrNiKNCY5gic2bIih@kb0F/1SKz4xDWSV6xEsVgMuCZvStspFmHN9yBy9pZFAn34BnavuI9oM20I/yZxYdzxS@7lylTT828@V410hY8JclxVo1eC60ht8xGRE3pJsq8Lgno1PlLmR5XzAzv2ZtbKjS/0@9Ojs51tg0H03BUMDE4aekcc7YrFqOhAxC7j3cOqydX8LZDVJtXa8BQhZlcntxwgfEQceagiWHTxf4ttik/SCsTLXXeA@yeDHSxFOkLTJoGQSvMfDBHHzvB5g28zMaNrb8bE9QeLH4/tjW5M4BAGviqIgfK7mQusjjTnZF@htOd9UxKse88a1B3QIXUowiGXOACExbTYLUygWcntPcHGDwmNx2bjeEdsNOatx1LeG4jZxNIlXZcnQSHGvXt7SiC8HMTZo8DQduW2i4rfX/O2B@Y8ba9/atb9Sq7yJh8PekKMvUFLWSBQe69sSDL/6Fu94dYZ/b5oJA3UqWPf9DddyL1VfoIJ8MpEMid8Tvcd/TlzxvAq57efiaC9VJi/v9T9Gl6qqDwTFQAE/s@q649Fs6L5bQ2ONQuVtmTYkWTVQndzf4wV0HwzDuu@X5m22SZziIwMU2@790fYSRRo5lCT3NwqXk/uqHIn1aQ5ub0rARBexprefX6rh1hqKZT@rodZGj6qw9vNN1T6C/88JBxkU0fHo55bzHVtqnzqzR83eziD0C/CUxv7M5ZgYiemnrT7fWwWg84MZt1g9f4fW4y3urloPbUFMZrDpcIR4DBymbpnRv0tqofdT632ZjnqFNvq5TGwV7kgWQGOT@6siRQGG/ZExWIb5co0lyhNhIuzVIJXuUMCLQ97RHV9OFGNn49AeJaGBeXgFyBpqaXcIv4hq3J7jt3cVDidLUMk/a83sVTUa2Nka7kBXwVHFjtcR@8pE2yncLd7VJkrtfc4NtFXNVns7ROKQH6uRYp@3mXZMcUMgv7fM9uxYhW6vOgYbQvmC8reRkgEl676DmPhsMA8lPLalv4v3GK2nScB@BXsESlUaGT48QPZliifwVn@dAMfj0CNTBHOB729xe58i7aqq/GNKB/RpT8JmGhifeCnU50rple1jz5ihzciEgUc5uuJbYxJWW2N3HoF7uKP8ZkFXIUsmaRy@pJRfjRi@02ptjR9@rg8JLTYZ@DF0fuV@i94artysP@aPvkvwalSMXjneQxb3B7/EPtJWRi8ZnsVDutYg7maI/@CF/tEWwCmp5zP4gTAWyOs7Fj/XG06M1eNNoLmKf3uC/TQZYH0jniZBhVfwfWfAeMskMlVFMGiT0/sC7qvIAgfWqOX7lpJdjdvuZW5hzPWF3GclazPsgNdSkHmrLef@AYhja3qTh2ifUSNWN1BVRsLCWD33G8sLHspzMn4X275KzuPRzc/Waj@9d6z6MzafMlAHykAY6KRmrN/eqhsgkaa1LPS9TAD9A84Y4cUjRCFt@ngDY5u7sirLX8JdrBAt9aiq@wdes3jRZg@i/ii8C64LAfbjs2N00G4TJpEG/K26MxAm0DwZqqlqgo@8vQUq4xEe675/LLlQcRqoLQl6z5o4w0N7nCl1ZQHNJCBhaGzPDuwfPerKKofXJ71jwQNnVs8vGY/iVf1zTUKfU01NI48HTZ4Y5EaGcH3i/rHJY5QjhH6JLEimNWVpSazQV7v8QPpc4XUFzlSkEW3Xfvt1v5Tv6mKScQn5MtjbL0vAKn3hxzKQ2A6v40dhf72XSvZi73eNkfRE1xef1w27k43r4VRrEgA73hqMsSed9gSTZh/Py6/mn9@ZibDnqN4UKGJIY6PZJzBgmbBvDg3trCGwWSAHg@Z7HLCnRsna2/XyLMNrLxoGP0m3l4ga63XYBwWF1wWyWGu1eAcd4CVkk/FE5kxV9yMC53JxHo/bTVmR8AhLXwGwFRRZCYuXx1mLbA0kS4ZJYCUR3d6iw6f5MXPMPqMEchw70P29hZUs1MrONbKEtWZFvT3k7hOHTp/Peei8U44R4ySgggwd3r2g3A6cKJGHRecm60jhrOl57F7l9MRa9mcMyMpaqDY9qH5NsNhIEai6tXjNWiHZwNMy/@WvevaCY2iiDTSWDOjg9BW8SF4dCwN19tFK1049qWkcXrCMccwGuG7j1H3pJDJmuJ5a64zVGWrmGjF72aK9jB9eqligtqiwChUbi3jNgmkVmkVNTxUssbATXsdaZYpX5clYAcXYMweGH9Ulshxhom/mpcGFwRRTx61Dz4sKqCfgAXGyyoQYRLKqjsiEO6bkv/yVtViTrDUBEcLuVfJkrfZWinhJCUtWSPK8OgGqV0iWgq7aIC7MZGiUJ7ivAUItWP5uvAKDrCIFSfSt1lDiZKx1lOlkHfmyyIn3GuCVWSeS6DpM1s5bt8x94idoTAv/9fdp95PNN8fXvmjEcHjRCuTkGcvVdnAYgjehTuQ4nDvsbOFV7WQR91qo7K0uLuwmxbVaEzkmC@KJ3AkzsiaSrBxQsM2BV5orBtQPeHUT1FalSRy6JpZh66ubKIw3ZICtyIHLWkJPVpjg9X04yuEcfY8GWFZ8PGLDDLxZDJHxktJxIrWa1AxuzzvTGaE7IXMw04A/EEyQ7Bw@JE7PiEsXeipe4X377d08wPju5tHsPW2smHN3N/@aCVwD91Rocw@/oXEFypYzT4f@M@b77w1ugRyOZ@eJNQ8PtfzwqVqoZuuNZKNZB24@W5k9yKn6mNtoCiwLZOHKQJXJ0nlgiy4Jxue1x1qDrN8A3OVChxw6xZt03O51wBrUZrXD5zi0nGsQMD63Y38m@r74hrAV/hrA1kyihGwtiqpEkGyZcRrbGtS7ki1cLri6g4mw5gheFLFHFRIeOVACuOQDLn0hj9DrXFol@JF4QDF@nlHv49iHAni1gXgNgJm0Tgvn1wq3Mrc388//DXKsQbv2j80xwfFujjHEezkGwE00EiOXLJSatexuJBCnzT4pMPB1vF1OJHXL2nFhSZdqr@5faSZiGxv2Kt61bjXQVDKI7YzlTcQtA3Q/SXUkU7EG1i7Wmj@UlA3Q5L0eqKbuwsSaDVS6nyy/sdbg@BTkOABm@dcNrRc5KAxrJF6v8gbNNeNBi31nRT4kcASzQe3ZlXIn0D/88z@3dqLcmeD@I9s9Z1Lw9if2mwjuf7YKYVl4@xfrtwC8/cx6@5bGrHy97t7KzZqJmIGtQhUZxLzHLBpz863c47YNt52SAgamNAZeTwnrMLiVrQ1nNnhcty3gPBQXsB0raayXSXqCfu/Cq6aPaRqbInhAxk8Wewhzy7gni6gfJ3gPETQldCQcCbFg3Qq@6QohWQjZx6sLLIRu9zFIJTWVtMR3XR6dnp4ih8FzspCInFgspw@5b4OO79aEHgIsZVkttwjiQJRNDAg7s6O5DjkP68ZRceV0sk50fwIGiVWC0Ka5iANA3NhbWa0UhEZTtVkF4qEIc5Mo/sXKGgNTSCFr2wRrJ9kKkQ8QWbjxVpeXUr5ZQ4DXVm3JvX@7GBxtDFbHYMeOfUJ2@y26M@@Ue3vHEwKB@dUekVPA/cd7tkGtpSf5egOO6@X2GZwb9KmuqHhdSQ6oRa4AHQjSbMS9VaccNiqgF9eg7wEl1Bmog7wgDVXNSKazhWKlWn@1gYRAOl@COZHz7NRz5/N7b@/XDucLqV8xNZWj65ep3IqV21RthmYxxGZ89iWZ@1J7SekbqbetxRuv0yYBrxJimS9FTMZCfDkyhfEa@yaU3gJMW5PLr1J1uZ@eb@9Pz@6Ug1fJf79vb92B/wgLF7juDLKzzon26JzCaklKA2@gNvyrNY4Bx2bn6HodqPW@8X57C8h6O/ZmH8hq8QtFFvCu1@9S/jeWxUDe/bSVFNkEYRG2ohd0zYpUFpO6SZCnXg2vb1OD7Ly83jluL21dM6lidWTJHjdOgT6MLvEWtEEUtNXdJRuyoMNTMDd9JOh34SFR0hVckG4PqIr1VH1PIgODnL5alroOqQtjyddY0YMVx2Zfh72hYQB5k6XuCZe4naP1Es/3tjf4DU2WTBfeazH34@4k5MblxhlgT/Fmhbn7NH5v7wtBq@0bHrIDpDoBflVVDW268Blh5apBLw5lJoAcxEBAxckY4ETyqAm4lRBQWfVBZOCjc0XELd7zYOfBP@6FIXX/QJj3pD60NC63F1TS1yy72TvC4c0PihP0sMWqc7wGYZsxP2q/yxbHuFvOLyk9Ye7CS9GP7zF3wN85a0@dbscrGSCbbuw9KL2Xu29WyoIz7Vq72bnyQiHE42tFsFt34nH/wKDwElzogUCKdVMvgRPaUJc45jTkmpDtSwbyI/LqunMpXsPU3ch3htuzGVKQx0P6LvAgAX5EYorEJcl4bM@FN/266ASUM/Y1lB5@LCUN3bJ@/z24SSJudIhHH9JgbuB@u5sC0xSiHBO00ADD3zGmaAa9NEyR9TwkyVJkAwJA7Q0mFbk/IBUQeEFyjc6@2azm36qBFlfj8WO7NHbVYRyBWJzu0RiAdo@aW9mmwF97HSVwDSsxgEpDp1QChfLpQlAUqK8ukJkx1E7ETUDIdLd3dXKFd7OZmaRwYJGYtxdmAqG7m5yzzidZBXvmkD4hPeCTZ2j3v7vDDb9oN/0L@vdoP33y5DqUEwsajDH3metwkGA9wSOP51A5ch0q2Bz55hvccX4@BGvnwe/wO@YA5DuU3Scgz2AdJQ6Vk0Pu1HXYSwSOSAx49XjcTxDhJwbtfzrknunDb8Ca8IKPbtVO16FBNh4xfj/7DPThGnJIe0FmnvAGHHLuBE7@UPJ4MA3@wwdMwE/ou7qHtCt3dZr00U9sI5fuj1dqZNdWWZfEq3M0LAba3sdrjR4mC@ytubeHFfD2Huc9Yfvso9/@9oCNQHfrYyToUj0fw8yJxxlmT5wH6OCTgz5y6I6nu4xvigSf85YTA/7H@@qoWr1237mCKI6cB@mKgw05vkXxwBFNHdBHzPdRmv7uu@/AEEW3Z/4z/7371ue8v3VZXakoOotGj7yR2JH3k/Nh03eLIrcrEHDXEY3uUBjdRTnuyBMKfFJOICiOryBiwYnvMfixKBxGWXz93f/xd7/4u5@Tv1@Q398gSZI0o9eDnzpAI7SEayQi/E/cy96Wm8PurrhEQCCY@WD9JbBkfgUXW3U6w0Fn/Vu8ye/jB/gj/3CtX/H9A/GxvQnI6@sDog7O@IPlAcuyBwvy94Dd7Hzr8s3fv2iWDdx9hQ9viXz49BXwV/CQ6/j404aRtCMac6gq8RlAEmGkHuCOwNY19@GLOpg3OPyHGl38VzPxX2uE/2o8/kO@1Aj/lZb477KL/3Ypog5@kkh43r3QHj@//2Hlog6@O/0u8Y@4cH6oA@gWHZyd3T8/e3y3/m89Jyf2PyiUk/UbviwXEHDv8XlOb09P/Wdn8zPf/dktdfAELHmmDgIOkPu7I@ogMT@tESpvM2er3OxcJfA59d3fVktg0Te8gVPfQSCXTHsD9WbqgIW38OYVBwbxay2bzFSaAF0tZZP17HmhlW1Wwd@4fzj79Mnjh6L5BPw5uweK5l97zjwJ0zTRzcORH33B9bDHZb1SB5mzeZP2nQLRJeqgRlLy@R/O7r@nDm4Pbl2ej56PjMxMGXbEji7Vyua/UplDgDRnhqrODJgB2wPJRYzQZBbMYs6M1QrbA6cAf8wYnBIjzpk@ozAKy4YqkcqnHWxv/48r6mVFBXwqxDXnjIlRMyI8@5XKJWAUIfUh/EkMw8yBzDkzhX9GZsn17QMDGXUzd3fULXJ8J4AW8rNOP@P0R5xO6T4c0R6fngORx1tiroTj97d4P@G9A3mdD3e3oGKc9ycHtHF3R1s62hEIOU7InsPn54eHTLKRfHig8UDP/PTQ88nj@wRX4sxzaj8@HvTOTj7eHfuwdFsS7n84oE8/3p0Ffdgd8QDDA@B3Snt@5LVBCc8Pd5TTNWu32/jXnk1nlos4LL@79joU39o0eFku7AUXBqX3xd91zF8LmMt1G75/ena73XfOE6e9e9eFyPZdB3s3D4go4HAT4z8OLScbxPZZJOw@O4uE4T0Sc/tcDAm2otw5NE27c/jJYIKfLD5LJJK6zi0IUAga7zsHpz/cOW4D94lEPEy8w754BKm6Lx50O9zub9nTUzuNgBu8Hc65Q9Wd6Ol5@8/19HzqIpcb/7nd2NO@n7ldEOwOw9v8yYVOXacu7AdeONbT8xl2ErgncN263Pfu52fLD@4u96mF88wNbMMjJv8N/1UDGRo0tM8H2OhSUCjsdnUXgjsUccU8cfsv8QEy4HIEnUHIl8PJOW9vPx0Fj6Kh24/3R/4j/HOd3p3d72lV3NDUQ41ZCXiCPcDsow78JzUHG3A4scCf8PaWYFnto2D8BLfIJ9QBRHPAdQDyCM3n6dnpWkg2bY37DKrkEyJcQ@575H5@AsGxAsEoc9nzGnd3cwbXXuRGJ93E4dMB93xC8KNnxwrclj@C3@U8IRNfjifHIaffsveOZ8fhU/cZW69HrJsYSeHQyclRyHJHY@Bmj9zWWC5YOSdrN4QIBsef4Ip@coDlwwlMdEOuEl2hLylgsW5XAE84HP5AB@Ax/zqSDcyP7OvsaM8VC8Q8R55Pt0dgyOOiuCe@33@gTvCskjWF5fA5rGqEYnFCxAEyjDgChXYqHFY989XfUebIcrH4l/1gUNDx6oKIzFCUgSZexjtwVFH8YPlDDxJ1BQGMeEGWV3vIoZ8h92bQqf9AHWCjCkw4Q4BrXOWEiSDMJpOZsL7SknHMDYecRq4ffvXTH371P/7w65/98Ouf/vDrX/zml7/4Kfz@Cn4/s54/@w/xML7/5pf/4n/54S9@DZ5/A7//DL//9Jtf/uvft37k/W/h939t@f2t/duCs34U4PqT3/zy53/5m1/@sz@D37@1f3/28vfDn/5H6///tv@w89c//Onf4pv98tOfUf/w17/C/z//63/4z7/C///rv/uHv/5X//An/544/txy/D//9j9Y97//g5/@/X//L//@D375xv2n795/@QX@v/z/wefL6fwSPF@Srx/r88vfiZ5/DDc2qYBA/eKPf/jXfwhy@qfY/U/BDf/I47Mujw3wR9jz@0OGATvn7vttyO9pFowPRG95/hH6/g4v62Y3kID/33xPM2AkMRbkGuc25B//5pf/8i/B9/tPCPxsyD9cRbf1zQ7kmk5swFtp/REA/8UWzB/98Kvf/@Ev/4cffvXnP/zqTygW4ZMjP6APVADhJ75hT@IgrvkRFQ6CWlu52Y07GCLuMNz32Zp40vDjpx0vC/fRPmAC@JGEf9hruuI0jla07Uvswyr@Xgwf0ScIBouFGC1zfMcv4IPdpKkjj5XX3AYk7xaM/b4V0/Kx3tFW9F1/7LkVcfXY520FkCRXQMhGNrcTRRv0djaoFWUW8PyVB4Xs7FFUFDWrcKsVzvONrWcjm0znqQhKVcqZF4@wDRRGpWyusX6NWqGrqOE1ik62VHr5aj866vFx4idsKErBE94m@KgP3MLgQ6Lm5BhH/@kpiPotc/8UigZC4VA4EIxEwtEAG4rEQ5FwLMiwTIQJBwJsPBSKx@LRZxSnqLMn3@kpdVbPNgBNo4LYAOOnzq7R3I@q1SvfM3WGxwUTVjMKqJ58hkFRuI39gMJRr9fv98MNP73kIk//4bcrEPbtztWBg2XYsMMRYQJRhwMaUt9Hx0JAAzRGQXSiQe6oSzw/FmethU0SRgkuXYjjpRzQMM8UspKmi08lm2hve8IDe2GnLvUHJjJn6hrAMAyw29cW/cqaX1v1bdTlOPz7sRekIGxf5vseppUG8XsVIr8Gp/Jgn4zxaR94faiJB4kkETGUH5dUIBCPhWPxYCDmjcVjoTAbCYe9bMDLRmPROOMFxsfYSCwMrPXGQvFgCCTCC2UfjkepA0HpSSJNQz@dhQ47fkoKjzemn@Id/qp/cEYd9AQRr/pBc1fPjQ56a49JDDmCsTsGQUQHG6HwDPzRPAEdPrw2Icgi1kE5OMSjg1wuzeRyDkcKv4DiZ9KMw9HDL@EYw0RTDodAQtIguAGINMBv2QiDd/k4JPySTuZyGMMQvwRiGIfDMbJCrBd59RIFMAW/BIMYAXI4HtfoGECuWhTFSCzTemGYVNrhmFjkxeAP4JLWW4gQm8UvOABHylkhaQhzOM5XkaA9czhqFpydVH6V32TS4ShYL8kkRlEkmQ9bmbrAL0lyQSQd3kB6HY4@OPo6GJ8ORxecWIYdDh5c/IIDvzG48Kp4xeQcjoWVD5wTh2NOoDl@5HA8rPwhHaAnn@cGZk/oW9dCt548BBUgSJpPsrnu@Xm33@/qi2T2vEaCisU8N1xM9G6/a0fsPsCl4lgQNBovXl4CDnp44OT9QRcQpLwIelg8CITCB@4RKLOvPk5o/FDEQUUI2jegZyOEawzAXXylxvBMcV0raHWRIPKcd7uOExBaClcftHC5n8hghgsZ0lIAreNivBPoYoc/TmKOSNRxfARPx0dHEJxzF2Kc0MdyOO8cDvdt/P6jIxp2HDs/fvQ5v2E/Ikc07jh2RKMO5D7RBXOiKyhw8ozTWSaYE/x8xMdxIc6L713cV3uy4bonz1j/Qgfv6dG19CRY79L9ERPmgi5kyOE@BkJPnmn6FFd/XF3hiVY6m8zkAFzM4QNFjtYAlp5Y13Pk84EWR/AD0weHawkrzy5H3IU7pEBQPH7nIF1Ia4zd5XRGA06n23kCSD6QA7OQRSemndC3yj1W8pD7eMCxyrwr7oOeNfLFgfJXtOijY8PkdDzbQpI6Ro5I3IG98UFg8detyCevj/UeH3XDp2f/5NX13/2Tfdd@X3xRVjsXYamDZ6qH97aH4ugE98ifqOen59MzO9ELtFhwHt@Khm8Q6nsOqUMn5oEzuDO4k0wk@7XkqqOdTFMHvqAaUg8ODw@pg9PGmSPoqPgf1gNXZzQZ@rzD46J4HNF/93D6wfM7jWr5/GefVgO4QDhN6QJefdjDJy1bo0uxMC6TPjIOPL/jBYlQCcBJneDhCscBrny8DBUwirfyWhk6/ckBGX1C1SdxopDp5@NLPNno4o7r5LiR23sQm5@UJfkpFvSdkekaLNYgHc9aPf5t9NvYt5fNSrOS@8Qcx45jhJN3d3bxe1kn6yQl84A@QRMm1bLUgfG9GmZ/ohRPDo41ZzDkDK7L4y5xYGWejboPzgJRv8EtDu7tpdSuEHjeW1NrAfagvXvNdl6mZOgakor9Xq/flwK/d/nd94c07XSukzo8e/qC6/n29PT5FF/PtgPfnp@fT1/9k8fmegNmE/67yY3/4eD@J75T6/8UbumKxRxHJOxw48XxxrcP3z4cgEKJI0cg7MBdDNoay9BW5smRQv4E4wj/fbvxOILoR@s34ejUQOEz6HuAH03Td@6rANgu8XgkFjmgfkvT760WgdD19KkoCLoxGe@bP03q0iWH55aV9RwqOC4nS3x24KfVwc0rIwdhKwcvEMBmzrafbflseZHzznf9FgaNV7NiX7CS8cnY5OB9JGKN6sKDfSZZlYiO8F4YvGjfTT1RXwGuCW@ShbBwO6Gor/CKTPzqWsF50TeG6cZr0Bg39dVXdvtgmH7DfMDIcSTb08eeUM8UZg/X6xmInJyIR4Gtlf4cXt@oataOUXmBrEgGaecse40s0sfpbhF8hESLCsjNESIpEspx5qzkv7LAuhMRk5IrlLIQByWQSJZI2LEdehefK0qy90F024kjBrwwFgxOOEXAMSCgA08Xwe0e4@0EvItAehCLw0Wy1AKgwHz1Ekq8SLQj3uLXe4iO0Yu8rBqA2ErdZeUAHT3Yydp5WDW7OBPAQpw70q6R5lnv81679PBJSrf3bvS0WrTswqHoFAU2q6ptXFAY1icBSER@3LPPSExs2EywsfdeKNoTa/Graw1n@2wY9Uwdmd7xiVVU2gl14eLdT3gq/uQn42@@4b/Vbsf3J@5xwsRPj2cMjezIJVkgR2ZinADx0G6l@xPz1uOR7hNj94ULv@OjSBkAFi1mG247b5BzJQG04OU6htu7vFV8P1HuvblbxQMkT7xHN4mll0sw3jn8JLBQZO9jgrXzAWmaiaVHOeFO4YdXBewsLAZLw8Od7HjhKCOXnFjecvcJ4IcMET2eHGQG6DRuZY/n3g2JyxD4OuKJ/M03nEc@m5/IPp8bQ30b/Ji7NcFx70ng92MXdzr/uLydQPxjFzwTkIzsBuIhns3r5zXtQN8J8Ngq0w3pFo1zTN4cyBsnEkc3H49ujhIfPixv577xvddi/zGzkQZM/BwTf7K1cNt1dONGL1hChu1djq@l46/9RwZyeCWPB5js1bZiWhQe3UCI5vGsqH7G@pKcVL5acYIlzF5sbJ3TSM5oIxM95PxLgxyxavbwtguImzR4SbLBrf0ymgR9Zg4ffe4l549yBAKH2V9OwIF3848fqVXS9vpWSBkrl66AONz3Jgdn63gOgXyFw9r69Tn9uk8Nr3TuusdZL9xkEfRug5Gt6kpUE6lwhs7fYhCsBp6Y5xNLY1mrmkHZEO0BMER7YDgf1iKYSbaesCETdiCU1qqAIBbWE6K1bREf8Wdg/YRt4XXNBxVikQGVeQ8ZkneYILoJ5EkCF5JOSXrggKpCfQWZwDTgPEj36AwUGfrmG2S/niagwx7FbQEGw3BDD4uBXlEKiX8BpYADUzkEGcX6kCQCtH2FQ/Cq/Z2EQv@4hOxNNy6I4Bl6rb03frL3xjVRDGvLGeab2yIDl8VXXw09iZBNEPyTTgbEh7Dn3x7Yzf0xSlcuq81GtnaZrMMd@kix7SOGV8f4vzq8W8OHcnclhaw857kaK3SKPEIusFtNfAgb/khHDxWbJRQIlDNefGQKsP7AGoGDBvV4jUkwyHGUhl/V@/RMGkn07ueA8AcVyCJ38vEh3@osYkwOaZzlzUa4zT44A497QWNun/Owc@zvWDAM@0xy3@ozL2SjLdkSOMY726AW2meYk/WDqyVQZMEdnubykmWcutSXyLc7BhaCnfjk9FjTik7qB4XPHu9xJoclmorHGOYYMV7sYFeOwMoRXDlCK0d45YisHNGVI7ZyxG0Hu8LMWpihQxsMRjbO6MYZ2zjja2eI2Tg3GEKBjTO4cYY2zvDGuUkttE4tEiN40cGKm6TqCjoOY0OxVRjeyKqYxDMMaNiXniEgNPAKEqKHXnlCerFdz2icsRMq0BUMFAhENu@gfVawCZdFldeiw2ulbL3ZntBWUVY/jQhsVtdBK2Xn@GMLIHTuY4Q39lAUqF3EywIHxoBggpWSyIH8C@5ja8OrvjjebO7BGBLs@h2i47OFIQ5Lvhtiic@e4MC@YAtbYC82a8cwWjNma2eUTaRF5fFOS2thDO34bWP9gBUs5ugbEAELApfB7laqVZoNfbI3yeD7Se4g3JvkK6IsvOF9sTBvXAR5YhWVtP8EW2KVnmWnCKS0wQywPxJFZOBFgeKdz4kn9tjxm1/@2f@GfvPLn/8a/fAXv/5//9P/jN3/Ed/@d7BZUGAN8LOf49u/wbd/hW9/gW9/uhWJwAePHT/82a/g9X/69@iHn/7cCvqXf@nwhtaIIAR7bWL@4p/i2x/i2//p8IbXgL/4YwsQR3F4n6kd08oFUD/7G4QgNYxljezP/gohhwcMDJctebdWHb/f2idpIViz4Za47l@GW3d8xj7wmHF7HIDXfmM3bx5cAO4t5DqHv3q0qXtgzlir7rGW5jl@gPfC2V6qge0fHpswquHvg7zNemD02CMbTsj9H6Bj5PRgGPAmG74Tlg6382/n27EJxbAeBw3U4XPBbVTkCwRrSqB7S4F8k57AwvDjbgvpkbKWjNj8LeOvqq0aEMdKssiB7JSd1io2dHqQ/XEackL/qquLhRY3Q9aGaXIwPWVv1mK3EtxRNy@KDVJ56QNdxs0Wyu2oxEMYa1AkEG3Nb8xY/EK44H2JblNydrXJVnIvKgy@umBijrY10jqhBHI4PgOLOW3Du7HFFdyFt@i1AW6Z4@D9zobMfcCO6@trB7Xlx2AZ0nsugmErU5bKWAexu0GBraDAVhDQbOEkuiYcCLyggTQcWC/ubj62om2pqN1oG@HCNWdVDpgM6AtaI5peUZ4Yg8Rr1EQj7yq718i3ULL3Cbue3ClE55whh/tVBMC5Gyfxsiz3o2ZewbwuqP0xMbd3fHZK621MO3G2KgXhHvWSS@uSY@P7Sm43wXdQs/eeL0wowPwjE/J9YUKR8OcTelmsOO4O@rf5@3m1s1ITaw2/QWZV/IOdBgo3jX8GordRR5hinThdbujyJO0uT3emIteerxCBP706I23n00P61slpuBNTVk3BGh74pKnQ5VCxFbz16cJ93yu1vxTYV1RdMLY3WkvWVjTFibf682pfgVbNi89qk@zvauGZeOtQl912Zd2y2VZo2voaIkZtMQpbng8PkiKZDw9gfMqie8NA/Orn8f4gJ4U/owiurfiutWlb0VwqPnPSdH8eJ7F3rWgNiR@5Kpod6IREkgg6dLwgQ@cLDfAXVgzVYgnOovXNFbBIu6bLjZk4UMdqX1BUfMoBjv0CfWGDGxPEaRqhxYs4L@K3KLI70S7ey7ntqBc/Oiq6COBvBK3iB3YR7DDDi/SXPMac1fck9/Bmcla0VXr1H09vfZve@vv0ipJumC9pJp54tAc/f1zSQdcGAwBuyAh@ngyvfbDJK3J2SFl74697WRG@mMSeYPDQ/GFKkwCatMH9IsiHd/1mwNua8NZb/H@/AFfRs19afMSYrS9A34zJx3hIF80gxzopvOAC8IIb657Xya1FO/OFadkdHdLD8yIHUVwK3mYGFVPTBMVwrCBXiD8j83iJ0Cu5J@uGElbgHpr0qReNAm8XUeahJ8jcQui5bEjvFt5VjmsC1yP66ssyjhUdUXqq9Uk3F@Nld0wxsh2YAB2/ITKcd@p2vy1WFoi0lh4yGUcoLLzNPzJw91I140HQhDUHouqgQQ/IiUHknCZtoS2sIwRk60uyth612h@rJMv4ZIXPMgT4YH3WifVuknW/pz5rrnWWvqBFWMP6d7OMdwmvMOJ9uq/L8Mex6PM5JaMM60iJVSnvWCdvlbj0XolvScVKJi2r5MtE8nNC98UytyVqFrKNCkv/uCbkFeY0J8s879rGaPm8W2Kq8konYD9cYqryRqvysEehrmMSTWfib2YkLPvCTUngLMBzCs8WPDFC6IM@WAK1yhu2a1dDXiRkzGlbVovtc8tjW3SLi@7tecQtKGrlxgO5z@s0@TfT5F@lye@kua4Bu0luAVH8TpJ2KeDiea8IZEE039DOOAj33OHxntqGS1E5Hc@9Pjkl57HkRc6p8xgUslNwHmddoJSdPedxhjgM53GdOEbO4wtwbOqW83vn8apaYAAdXonjE/a3VTh@553HaZf7mSLfD1@l63cer8sUYD5ar4Qjz9bwatee9VfXo6oC/l4fNiq9CEuMAQ8VZ@v23kt@DPwTUPsYPgj8kECBIwKMOyA7jcZWi2GlA82Gn3yg2LWv@TheDU3Z4xubMRQI9yS2BlWwlEyIPnIeOHeVkUUYDiWDj/AEArHePN5PEWJf9cw@R46duoS/lAjM3k2fcM9P7IGei4TfAvD2II68ib8qr10UVgF@GZ048lt0viJnlRyhCC8GcO8hCzP1O@c7mcJl/eJIN6v0t0vo9RgBLkTfCsQqJYJ2S6eDDYdtU5KYpmq7QkJC8WyftB0HX3alxNL7IhrRCnbNfCOYeNs5w4phu/K738vOVjxM2o4KwoG3zL1Vy9btAtHFOGij67YsVavyAQlbOqdHzlgRsNhmbCeBs9SNl7QVbzVDq7hWkkRz7apJiOzHOzgnnGmlvpmXwfs6f1z3dRUTTHCgESPYirlOxdKv6o@w31XLfl8Z1CsmvEhgn2G9vyl9bV6/28q@oFzeJPu6AHGgF2Xce42jdQoblkPvYMsyf0/WXpn4@FNqlpFvJbrG/sLaX7Ft3Sf4DN9e9i0sXNhK0Ke7niM8MDsKvM2o1xaJPPWvjBY/TsnGY2V8Tekma@/TamV8XxHjENxGw@NHF7C@W8DbhYfxkQzoL1hu1XL8xWsyT7Gu2@QbyZuZC2vWQcWrxNYHFG55gron69fWS7TAo/JQy1TKpQ40utFo1P16KgLXWoi7acepd6cJ1t2WgBefMWV94ljFK2l088Od4ni9pIx4gDHAkXkbS/zsOu62ddmWPn9RdyGeBbvFURvXaFMNuB2thE0dDjfZks1X6xh/1xFnI1mZt8BvL@mt4VkjLB14QufhgTRfDw94cc7Dg92K4aJZTyP99sD@kl9gs16DOthdzUQsLuPVQS54AGAytr5JbA/A2Ue0WOtQDvDnk81V7HWsiWJKq8UOeHzI/gSyNZfvCrJ4dKIgrn0IHXhRhisQwl3YQBhviLdiYWg88EmWVtrpfLAMHXxSsaGpCjlrkpzfRcx2fG6ysRp6JWRPlBlHloFYqZB9/FsUWQuyVvNi1oeXFXIGL8TFe8HIEPKKN14k9P1kxicQhy7HSNKsIwjXSz8MN4lECCZrtIDHXVkYA0l1kN09o8mXEpTKICf1@yBItP1tCmuBS4ODqD5V9KVXR@scoBYnS73VIa/2mjBywLI9DgzsdO2cjWSgQASsqbgXOLv5AWPxMhmEzz9iyCItAgW/KDyiljPm3Yr7wbVw7z7Z1eXG@D64HnDJWptAJR1/h2LKKVt8tveGbg1N25OWRA9szVyujvmi7GPZEmSe0o/XqGkux4FjdfgZdlrLJjiZX50a5MLnVR1TXylE8eAVYIi31taAgatgo41Mr7nXS1IV9DUKBsiHdSE9YqWSZAGHNbO3gx3CICom1lrdZysYx9c9x9d4MpH66gDrQkvWcPyVKGM3Oe51I8vog43OmlDBVdmqAquX8NZLELoaX@1J@IPL4QEsHofbsYMJ4O3Zj68szfs6KihF92/pRi/SzqnJZLIxZvXaebKfHCRrHXhPMSVPexjK0nQ2L/eSmUJ3ca5GG1MxwDQ6V6lu0FON9uaalB@n81qWkkKdsecmOI/nQ8twOphO8sy1eF4SQ9H0tXhtCElZiNPT4eiqJ9S0Lqsb0kX5slxb0rnmVat/NRRv2u1hVKlTWu0m1b@aC1extjJtNeMF40popcvmqDw0J@yiEm1HmjPFSLUaqUFxUZiN5oWI2pHC6Ssh2hK1/IxfhDU@36Rupo1BpJ5fjOLsuLdIpo1eJ@rx0J10qh/L870bsVhPX/T6ergbHtXjXHA6LoraYnCRVx5Lw3R9ynu0Ya4QmVJKtTCdCaH2qCvnlZtaq9XNpKqzEWvcaL1hqH05MbsxPRIMTpLCYBgKFyamHiulkhdRM5MstHLydcu8WbRiVcrMm41os8jHZc@0YvLBSaZJG0xrXpQu6rNIPtBQ80pRLgyro/PJeVXWJqNMSKo0xiG9f53rqoFA/qo@zXdKlB4qtjux2jAQy/Bznr4Iq@o42IiXS/rlfJJ6rAjtNF9PCd0IkwpfZ9nhZWXBV6alWq1d1drNcdS4YOWbHDOkKtd8PZka5UrjGNsoLwqx80J9kk4X5tNuQOyryUmvHby8jsxKZaHQvqKDeW5iXnqkdEWmh8WisWg1LwrXZeMGqvVlUQqJi3mqldLFx0zauKyV6LI@GtRDQ6WntaJSWuWL1ULILIyS@Vn7Jl5IjQSx2h2po0Zbbk9MKTOkc9QiPbpqdoVZTlrOuGyo1Lqih9kab0aT/WCdHopidyRXjGX/vLTs1yfdfi9eOWcywuNFL9UK17Iae5kzQmVlQXUaKVFa1q5EdlSN5ws33WxSulTC6aqgVc/z03kg0JHE6iy8ZOfXw1xImvMhplRJXV96roqBmqfkSaWqarDSpwKZ3Hm7H77wqDlhSZdE7jGa9uiTSWiemeCvyZeaiqyPwzITyzU8g6iht@OXl7OuUbiupdu8vIzdXI5GkZsadT0tGKoeiBVzyThdHTH6OTcsF26ikpILzVLncjZeaC@bMTNbmsixfKmfKdb0TGPMX8ez/fpiMerHikK1NEpSQixTqw27/VZ33qkb1QVzGeKHXU/2PFt@7EM9btVzgWIzFelPasHWRUaZVhs5z1K9bpe0dHnEZquxSaQRDY6p6bwYS9ZNRdIy55fxyNVEKmWTmX4zzaqCcP3IX7Ajrt5YMDEjql/lrq80w2M2umqoO0gFF1eXHbp1YxjhvETdzNuRQnKk8xe9uVk0og0loFauGPZKLDfl8LQtPXaq6jA5pi@a10u6O1vm5lWTN@sjNdyLhkfnc@NRX17oF1SsM@TkZjmtloZ85KIjLaN0mFUanbR4yXeKASbZ7OcvhVx@2l82hXFgmH@c5HmON6rJTvdcjkznmkcMxqYlqlFuX/ejj49MVyh34lJy1KxVC2agwdGTTr0Ufix1DCPHNwtSKiQpk0yqcz4ap28WXMOYLyeNSFcWF1U9wGSpeblz2eKHat/IGTf8cHmdu1EuJ4HIdWUoRs3eiB1LbKklMtGyVvNkPFX5vNtfRFoTYcqDZahdFTQ2lRwOK1SFHUenqUXcMJVz46LcTReTUjJZigWutEA0P0qf5@c9qdVslfM9Tg3ddNPBSKXbZwK9VDnbr4bG/Wi1HA2V0lSju7iqsb1MTGIHnJweFhchLV4KpCJ0a1bLXw0bA6Usp5PtuZgK8g11Fm1zotIUlpEofcl4hoN4UUkyoWqEapoZs1nKzYIe5aJwGaguFvx1l5sEOfGxY3j4znKwrLQETpUHpcca22hNSmlpOGxFUnyDqaTqzGRpzDitVKXimarCZkrzaW42qLcZQ8vktVh3Xu6lq1Whq/WCmtitJOciM223b66umhVlfH01ztei3cqyxw3DLVOsRSpzk3oEk6c1LTVz3XlGNMRhbfqonM8n1y061Dwfl5q9qWcYv@lMg9J1hSmVUy2RmxSu@lGzWZ5rl0VZlOlxoNKnqVmzulyaQlLNlmeXnbnYWi6TUsp4ZOcXNFc6L2SuTU88m0tmKo06p8uVynkpk@TGs8tZ6TrqEZb1y15YGj3eUFVFkQP6TV2OppigEWiGM8s0PzxnJuepcaPYiLMa28y3Li8v2IHMj/lop5KJtC/5djJZvFgURa5VrWrVi2aDqniU65ubBl1pyKW4WCrUGmq4MNUv2@0oN1OTVxxTCI27s9I8NbucTNrjeNHTMQUuqC4Fga3N5BIt5EF2YpQwmVbT5aqxCDwuh4/9aUa9bsWT2nkkmV6IvakwXTLJzNRDG7n5rBeRtFig0Zmfix3@st@/qKUGQW2qNSLpMFWMi5dKq5seXMYXwkW@1MpNTKHe64Ykj8Fow8ZVsmk0@YV0zkcG06bRkaHyiVq4kUrHDfkmE7vQJQ8T41MU377kqnRpEL4uF3vqLD2/bC0y0OWIsWKVCasLpTWJjZT8hZG6aD9exGL9Zjc/goQng5sBLzU9qV5XuBLlMnVzfdEaZauTFj28ur6MVpt5T2wZ1M8feXVwzsUXjWWFYQQx3p8WJvOgVuJj57GLCi8X5@VaUxT6kXrgSj5XllRGiQ6YpMjOpjOF9izCqVi2L6aaZUXPNPl8VFCrHE3P2zdmpX0duwicM1dMfTxjAsbljGbEjiItOuVOJ9CjUlPjQmvX2WnWkzeTnfqwxp/LdLldKyzVRSkbMJrJclq8mMwWWmkh6cEbvnSelqu8xIJZEo70G3pztExNu1RbnJfSqVj0JpAHCTIMOT7rhDiBN7T@fEiXLid5eT6cjFq6Zzyna56bzjwcH7QGBs2XSo1yYZbVw2rRGCpUJMIH8m1dixq1x/GikDYzg1ZTDqXjrX63ku/Qlw3xIn6Vrt9EhXCVLjwK8XY9wvClcJun2Zo6nprQIvH9EVVaMD2dlwWdi04qj@HsZOLpLaYT06PdRM8vYu3@KM1Oec4TTHbVR27eKsqMVI4KfaPSnk2vc22wEJXWtKlQuZumFryQ8mI936pcjthqsrY06VS8zV@H@h2dFRVxWgua4WJB6Ed5MZO9GQ0z@cJjgemIj8yMlfWrq2Auz1JR0ZMy1Z5Mt660K2UZ4IRkpxK7nPWW6fGgLAr5QiCjd2qRXv2Ck7PQjEqPJUZr5c5LN72uPKBFVanUawxD3UQC2fZ17ZGd9q6qy4Y6z@v9YrIqB6/FgqJWr1ts5kqny9FU7io9rN2kF7FIVZe7QqMfayhjz3lQ5bmkUopQUWEqpFptuilIQTY6X3a5kUCzN@3RKJanlxFjSScVYzaM9Zfx7vmYbd@U1fPGYkSfj@c31dQ1OxE8LFvlNerKXFbD5@dtz8XivFnoy82CyNPceDE08qmJUJx1ryJJT0xjGp5srzWYl6p9rZ2lo91ujK0Hg@2Q@dirLoyrMtXKlPLBaGZhzsXsaFKex/JaMlJfzJtXodDoZjivxOqRWnjOTtVRNqXl@mFavTaiyryR7@dSQla8FI3LZZcfU5HlpFzIxbKesMB1qp0bRszSj/WebA76YuPiOliP0Hw4X6nObm4ySXocFYfZgnwObeKMu5wv6sPOqHtVMYISpVY6nkJkGVnWb67KPaXaLl4OurN@NFrV861hfLLsaDWp5tGWzUJXPc9Ux3JmeQ0CF6nFw8OmnG22petMjalQZqSdnIENzqZK0qJPF8LMhagwxfn4PH49bkdGnVErPa115qNhpB4NqxNhGTXbj@GJ0Ix2iuM6zXc7s4EncE6p9eXiOnsV0kvlmVYyq6pwwcQCpZtRc5ydND3j9EWua6bbjNYNtEuziScdBqsgdtmKB8rdi2GqMDq/MvJXgTjVyEmLSWx4Hjn3VKExmQyNSqwlB@Qp3abl1mwqjMYMV85wLX3ebeZKvXIvEKM1jxSdmReRx2KnesOZWkihKWMR6c04Tz4LFkRG6oTrnpapMWPoizDX0@CF0g8GDOW6XufNtBodNYNxIZTTW4ramqvDVkC6Oo@OZrx0MaRSwrIXkpu1dq88X8568VGox9WnzWTuWmkH04o2mBs6G4lfBFrcY3WsByumVi01@ZRyNeY4ceaZy6nMpV6fUr1@Odlr5x4n4rQVqiRDycV1jwlNbqZDVlleZzuBYbWbHIizWju0rM2Cqd45q9TGkjbWAzTTaCnZUWzezAsXVHGZFRaD2FWq2go1L4bxUVDuj@pVZjGqSCJ/c2NM2EKnX7pie4VwK3UVH@VFIylEm3GxOKTn5W7lJpLuCSGG8gwKYzqQLvHBYvbaYxZ5OfwoLdmyuYyLyqLclLr1/jSplXrD5qScytMpNjA9n1fGwXyNDk641DiWudA7ukwJ2XBy3qxcRozBTdJshdRqYBrTbqpS/zrQqw44fsxEYqCDL3vdm0UzWUvNSp1yvm4klf5S8OizC@W8kMulFCovtsuPxiOnipNkqFkpda4er5J6vxHumkaBnT8K9GKhVIppnl90kgVjVG4V60ohyox7qcvo1aBXUppqVQpeUHw8OrqO0kqdL04YIVRNhnKPrXP@sTCN1NSRYvKN7A1rlmug7ArhZkXrzMbL9IAR58FQ9tqo9HvaDdTW4ZIKTPK1Tq8mDpX5rFY0WxfBcZ0dtWbyKKJwmieUjVcqHNsP4k5Y@FpVxqp80Tev6@XphU7Tg2VkImjnwoVElQJaP1moRYoB7vy8k4k32fFjSQjELkOT5CxQqV16lLCgZQr9scykR7WhcCVBl6EdqQ6LTL0sNfs3k/R1fFGnlp2uGFeK7Zl6kR7NMqPpsNGcB6F71WiVDKNeuzZ7hWmgW4zK3cqg18jk0ld8muOMaEVJZysjbdLqjmf5UJga5oLXw8toUepHRtGCsOhcTLR4tbgspAf5kKejFGNmhzPlx4o8fCx3TbP7GJVa9asi3U5FeYV5XETN60GbNqh8bJw9DwnRZWHARpvKeDqZ9Co1RS0sqleXwOZoINg479JJrX1VNVu9vMBf55tg6RdVoVC/Lmr18@t8b9JTKDkI4pum9YvzkpG7zoxu2FmhtuhKrGdUuZhVwtGwGO96puFxeTDJhMPt6LhYnuYymh6ZX4LW71cX1ZJQK19S7Piykx15iiLLxvTLZWsaqiWF60j3cibOQuFMcq4MYrEmM78qnvNXsa5WmI2bRbZ/Rc9u4iNjzDW5WpJXxQqVetSCi8zczDLh7EUkf30lDCOzXnYSKCRn9XYhYsbLYrsdepzVZiOhnGPFxnw6C1RzlStTCYXnraub0QWUQpji@/OrbFS4DAk9RlrepPWc2lWaXJKhi3Rg1mxdedS@8lgWPKNqIBfUIllmXuWgZ3yTmhR7kW5zKLfPU/n4gOqF@KynYUQKN5HH68dLSb8eeqJjUDkxsTa9ugSTpGs2G6H5lRjvsMtWOtbmurklm72gk6F8fhIvBALFUrzUoYx6eAzS8jgLXBczcuCq2mqEJp5MOTPvDeo3zVp6dhm76bDjars@LeLOWJBmZmJlWGsuyrl5UxIi2VEtK6YoT@FqZlTimljLtLI6Xe2JudBwlD/PnQuTC34yzyoepl9oLqaPk7EQK17KnKAruZo5SPLBTmwUnPMFLfl40aIWeS5bZNOxVkwfSXxxWG4aQ2Pa1kQpGXoMzz1mbViVLsKZWuNaGTYH5bLOpy8DUUPIjOrjyE1zOO9OhWyvSIlmfMrL8/NyxFRSi5x03by8KvbqzIKvxorlnD5nunTusc5MTboZq1cb/W5Zl0pDaDg9naaqxmRQKeZAvaI4bVBgZq3kRS/WN9LnTKxUnFeaUtnDXGVrw0zAmOoeejCuBDJLNVsMirNov3Z1MWb09LQ38FxUo/TNMKXOylTY7AXbnDGK10S202nRWra2NIzLWLPrubiSaaEWuImm8ku20Q1qvcmgE@uMz6ePnc7lY7dVz0NxXnuESP3ykepfXeSNqBjn2V4zlS4l1anGFPVxTQyNS2qnGeiIns48U5g9Bi6Y3LDQZcvlwXKZ4ot6W4llxt3LNLcYNmMtKpitML2boKAVm5nHTm4wGfLp0pwPXqt5w3MdKs8n53osGmFD8SlnBFvjccsTS8qSJxocLAaBVHYaydA9vdamshVPuq2qUAtqNxGuTBuhXlk2jWa0Uc/Ga@lcOl@6yF6LpXi9wF1fezpXhXQ22YgULwaj0EWHNVJ06nIwrAeoYSk96tGmGZtIdSlnZM/1zHxwM7oaT7qz6LRkdJbKBTeR@mNW5LRRu6REI8mr1mO4wgSzl3T2ZikrgWh4Hqd6vNgr0nJtdN2OSdk83ZEH0IHOgPyPri8nOi/qxiDehpxfLpVoulnpt/S8PKgChXJ3ovHiOC6NBkLwhqrR9Vgu2pYvRL7SqY2jna503SgGo@JkDv3XTmZ5IWZoKPVmpz6YMNeRLJiuodBjoT0YX03LLaMWzrQapWqIaj3WMiJbyJZKrRuzx5YrTD83NZvRWD7L8uPUqJxdpLqpwizHN9t5z9ATaPT4aa6VlLOtHmfMFzdMnNGT4pCKDCOXKTHDmrNwS9RD6eKgEuTkgjqvFGPauFYtBlLF7JWojnQmdZVcXZHWIj6Wwou@mEyetwqddJ9KXqUzw0BLNPia4pkVCFgqJ3O//dFHhQi6rhAwaqpKPfwlKEOwj7k4eefgCXLyBN7evnPuBF7ss32QgGjvr7a@FOt1NPEO4WMrETK36cdfCcFTiycv5xZ97Oo4AfLA53igI/JlEHFnItSh48hrMj5IynsEkBlPMoOC58HI9uSvjWP4AQ3eFUpgE9lR5yK8cX@WNsIRfM4HPjiUuT/ZmvJ0sdvUYAKhyDhFBH56HV/jUxW@gYhkCjhbybn3TeszJzvxgThDU8hJIw6f30Gi2qdiYEy7KKzSxP7rsxkociDLamLtne@ecTQbYyJxcr4HUrymd3wbv/ce8QkHEkyJU8bGRJ/1Rn11MBWRjLRhd84vlo8IhUMIH3MU@MY6VJSNJGhyonMU7jEUJ4dAH67O9CSH2OMzvcj5jPgIUSdC6wOtTj4gN3F48e3YcfJKStHReCWF1iEf49vIfUJJMCfjW@X@RPF43KYnYXpYjwt7fMO6T7SJvRLx1rwnu/bpI3S52lqPvwqC1/6q/19x17rVRpKkf1NPkQjbSEZXbM/0IsAWILBmuA0SdnMwjUtSAdWWVBqVBGhsfuz@2BfYB9iHmwfpjS8iM6tKF6B79pyZPmNKeYmMjIyMjIzMjLhSx0GvdRMsh4rDzcffnLDvMjOBum4/Pp9uvdYwGMRTrsBPbjcxEaeTcErsTtT0A1NuOO57OLqzXgk6AfEv/lkY/elteTofPVxYgAuNsr47Ee/Ad6c/anb81pqzwPTEETie06@taacwLQW@XVjgNF8SBRflh2lkl01uK@iPdWVfilyavqzHQG6mcbaayT6npCnVJJ68RAy3ARWTIkLeRHFFoPloNCNY4Xvf69lzUPjxyZTh5UQtmjzj8QflwTfsd@dyqHz20kN/1pUuyj4wVEZ7nODUcx@P3vgqweayZC38Our2@fw5L/hqiiBA7WXf9Qe2Zj4cNfG6V5VADN8gjRHAxwNcv926Qy8@NGYscPGNH1@hP4B3zFGGCOGWi7DdJBvx@ADw2gHXWZAIyGk1DORipaCh63I3MnqoiXDwt77cX15TfA@uTEl8JFqO5f5KuejrnOwuZXfd4c2c7BvAHoXzsgeUjbjIc7J9ypY3kbPzA8qXk/45BYa45UnsejkMLoeu30mLQw@4AnkQgZ1WKyuGsJYFlAyMjEeyvtKuUdSijI4wW4K9aH4yW0kBsHRaTx78jriFc@GOPi18EWtTaKK@qycb05cjicSX3BKJXbSfeZ2Ar2II0PwjUaqm803jMtq2own@ydOyc43RJmK9UT9@PIaZZsQk/5UuDPfJCOEebqyHQq0IjoRtjcZVKv1DV5pdR7uOiUs3c0ci6oeZlKuRCJG5Fc3rK7/XpjYI8GI8GVeeMup9lHIeXqg1Kz0iOsq0eJqOq1PcgxtRPCOzqhl9tp5PVRd8TzVdWpGbkbCAnzC3PEXO0JbOJUtvUmlLzQk@ayV4Rs/S39vZ5/VmifDjSc20KYugbZFquKkRnIGeK@MalwkC7MXymqQjyKyfBObPASb@9C4JwHCdcMDKZsS4WRP9Xl7epJKcL66@zfIVcynyEJHJCKvn0On/YXKBcHrJHiHuXlIkqRmkmSpu@w16bU5OuYnuiaSf3blzedS8/H4ZOKppfmKue0@r5JoqKuu4qawenpZDf4wy36PhS@g7YXq@rDCDbjjxOSz4MIfQTzJZsgurFypBcaDAkuGJJYmdEM5elKKr9ZcmxVy7lLk9VwMDVuVkPnAWgCaDFOV4razWuTYj0am9L14OjXKTjbQwhLsVriCVvezExTm2c7u8eMdTresopkg8By/ZoWEODGb@ldFtSQ029fKtSwyzEBn0pDl9HQTttFGYtMLAEIyHDiqUFXdWVq0S9TJqnprTSq@61l4@zLpbppRFncTrCiVA@dS8CSReX/O0KWPaxPQbP@RozJyP1YiaMq8PcFlRpI9am0xHaasCLcysZCQ@fJKx50ot53klToiH1Lbbw8VQDIdsrddTSLcDgTKbtNGO/FvyGDzMsDKID0/t3fJ7fOvil/08dGI76OYWZKZssVlfT6EZy/APvy0tFkbhoND0ewWvd0tKdXPsLCmvJwEB19RoeJX7CReFKyd7n7Q04XvZfAmR2IRGCq3le95dGmVIc4YX0VTGEZ90fGmx5MAFMd8b73i3bdL6xWNLPwjv@d8xbRaK@VF/GHCOboh916kf/o/In2qRXxHpHYNGZ53hRGXSeF8gqWO5K5kriYJUgnvlTAzEOWqywE19SaUwfkBU3yc9v3DCvOe2boAEeO@HbKdouJiTH5zQDD18rYEUeLxCnx3xMtHnu6NogrWTcMy/qfv4XcKHpPAVV/C93qc4fCEYOZ0g6IPJcRUU9deJAEL4hXpjp3pykteRlOTGOm65yz1mPBFkh3UcmcFe48VtdbgLlEFZQGcBW9rbiICz/GUaoVlNJkyFO5BTaAV/hNKDXIl/TXXDls9IcSYJP3fSv0LQsqi9evRJjwLtomrpWLWcqWYKx0ix8CQ13FYLjiAOvG5AGG97nQ4hLbRYiMiBT1DEtL9i2w/P0eaFRV7yc1P5uUR@XvIFqahUvnUziAqtxQullr5H5R5UKiqWnWprQ1Gna4fsXSofDGJ4lx8rG@Zpk@ZHhTftUApX2oz1REYulvPLjNGXnMVEHcvgNv9c8jV/r@qRt1gmyn5Ito@/jh4gj30w6CeLE1ya7/md92J@tDksYRXcKkl1jDeznUxKbRDR4iRHYoKYmKft5kYEZaVkJA7PmdTm@odUXpuk3qcn0ZBAgFMTa8YciVGJ21xhwt3zSkLtcPZiDATDBKMpM3M3TeWxrjyOgUWpRdOsYzyFJic4dW1yim/gWvcP/GMmexI5U25pduaCYH4vnZeXFkkCsdBdTM0mU1KaDAcjTxJ1px5ZRaK2x5MQZwuJwwA70NYNJIVt05P3IFfBqNdetHIiLiiMpJiiu83RlI4KlAz7zhtCZD44vxVeO3tul7TCjnevKtCpXXbK7yQe2wy9cBjSHPCogwMVjvr9jq/9uqk7fs6hYwKtvsNjhAhiTGnIOzU8EJXyWXzpxzFUKa@OAPkO7wyjjHB0jWDssAQjrjiJ1iufQA7zTqU3Zs/E7AZtVZ68eGoEP64QwB3a9sWQkJGT2cOWB2hpecc8LJKuXsn87g1JBaKOB@zzEK5W1xznbyO/9W17T60Wi38uFd@UYiQzpupi/s1bVYupSCZjtVgqFt@V3jrOdtAfy9PGdCsDWG9zAJhV@1joPxFvereI@@1UaMXggiGp/qE3uPXaecc58dpsA26OmCJg5RHI1TN@XpFCuhX83ZO62w2zirZdNxAv@Iv1WXzXttixRtbBG6K@N@j6Q3lpFNz6bRDQvJu6Cjqd4I4N0XiyJPRApa43JKK8zqgkSuyXVuPCugu7iyVqILwDO/BrBrfsR1qTgfRUH@73@QGQAyeKgBBvrNeewITaa3Vcvwt2moEAvCxFFDAIUNfao5b3KA4OI/E7cVC6Y@2gNYJnXteMTIGkX8Bzhaa7N/BJ@kYE5lHhajHcaYAbH2t1VT/abXyunFQVfR@fHH2q7VR31NaZanysqu2j4zOOGqY@Hu2TdKmryuEOpR42Tmpbp40jSkhV6lQzxRlO5fBMVX8@PqnW6@roRNUOjvdrBI3An1QOG7VqPatqh9v7p7RY72UVQVCHRw21XzuoNahY4yjLrZpqTlRPHe2qg@rJ9kf6Wdmq7dcaZ9zibq1xiMZ2qbWKOq6cNGrbp/uVE3V8enJ8VK8qdMzZqdW39yu1g@pOntqnNlX1U/WwoeofK/v7Ex09@nxYPQHyiV5uVQnLytZ@lVvifu7UTqrbDXQo@tom4hGC@1lVP65u1/BR/blK3amcnGU10Hr1b6dUiDLVTuWgskedc9JPUIXGZfv0pHoApIkS9dOteqPWOG1U1d7R0Q7Tul49@VTbrtbLytk/qjPBTuvVrEL0V26aYBC1KJ@@t07rNaZb7bBBa8bpcaN2dJihQf5MhCEsK1R1hwl8dCi9JSIdnZwBKujAA5BVnz9WKf0ENGVqVUCFOlFtuxEvRg0SERvxbqrD6t5@ba96uF1F9hHAfK7VqxkasFodBQgm2v1coUZPudcYJ8JLPolZHcO5WR5OVdtVlZ1PNWCuSxMH1GuaW5hs2x81zWkuF5yZR26PHuBNn/JpU8jjTuK3j3aqpPFJdJhUlH5Ki85PycO7RB4tNDaTfupTUF6rLttec3R96feuAmzNbTU5we6G11lEVMogYu8X55G44vqgnCssLV1efqpc0j63fnmZyT6nZgKNp2poL6yPlcroPnYCt83b/IRtKU6ozVfa13tWHC/HbS2vrPEhowqFtqer4fEiABszkQ5KQMDakIz8qtHtqViTfMSctBVxxIxJY5E53gxC@qf3I/oha0MsgYSz3FsoFLCHZTQQ@URZ/KkRDgqiI4PwPQD/ipvMh5737TpdjDeHLb82UGVMHS47pG3gdTrzRPWmdz1RPTdZn5HFW1NWVow7eOOmHYwZ8C9NMqXHJT/gnqXFtMd/MgYbboiUwow0xQ9Z9e2T9CupDv@iYivMlK0rcQ4HclD5ufYZm7ni6tvyRPpHmy5zC6/OEduG1rtzrnfBfz5eSAGaYD62X0QSfyxHqoVCrA5pZaxP2sLwVX@DQnd@m9ZULNU3Hi/r8JAv7oLj9WkxHvj3cexJDO@dVA62Tnd3SXIC27c/vfvzn8qO9rg/GP6clb9naAehNZm6pEXf@aSmcVZslmyT3rM7FSwnFt0Ho4eCCDZpBo0TXVJpredM0REkvoaYgdDdEBEGegiykUKQgEFK4X2@t@gYfp05MzUDpBNdzaA3XfeeNXyXVCXmgZZ4yeyMedTu8Q9g2@lvprjtkGYgzWJetz8cE@fS5oLlXmrXOBzgvQ0/K0aRfMrwcd81d5CEMJCZ7IUBb/D5l@bt2CiSXouBxnzlYeeahMTiJBYmSAuHXKImjoPQzGBJ9CnlZ81v9HmmgwMhC6EeKsM6kXHX1syZ4D1ic9YTQ0O@2NygIXr1yra0rmBIzWikxP6fDB0Tnw2MilxoUBOAzc0jS2ebw0boD8sZ9V04FV69AaesOVb/Js6d1R0NpWxcouvfJoKMElhRQBlOurNtOKbImSliyZkg079ED4b/b6TJDPjrtOEk6BG1WA77vZH3TEoyVKEV7V6ZKP6duTEWu6YWUTOedBaBeYgPzI3tmL6Gdy8HS0QCPTpjk3AmIcXSMwgAJoddIz5/4cCXJ/GNSzunDzx3F@Skf9BrdftpE5DLLBVTcC@yrHNlzRU5/MjIEX5RxZrbR3yVD@znkWUGNlwkxZpj9TJMCYyVEsscdLrwmo0edpYza4IMJTPDI3Yq6qllJv@9vmEUrTJtk/tAquj8YF/2OAQxhRIC35yAGAHCd5/iHdZkozY3gejMfsPTC1v5lV7FEeeSRCCvy6rB7jlC94r3zFiKtC8NOO1Ak4Dzsq1jNjW94R2Wi45AZx8iETSVfsluTNCItkVaNcII30yeqM6L7J3Fns2U4FeL/WnvWw9xlj0xcZkS@UQEqLgL1rw6cDkYVOd5/U5Fja@ArJvJ9ms99qvSkvNKmOZ4506tYKf/MowoQhrnHbRLWociKrmtb0hMGR7173L@Pf3htnK65yamEe0ZOGLdLKX/Ye6GALwycQdWpb70rBFpTRayjZdGfcGXzF37dYYvbWfeoE4RcpSCC7NaDQLK0JtwSXN6tjF@Cbc6uHy6RprT3V2@6Y66bu/K7fqdMd86/TW46RXC3ijs5/tjJ5VKJa2BcAQOFymE@9BTn/1eO7gL1RZNBxiS6oen9eOk4S9m@doWy5dSf6E21Ba37EyBv4LPpDC4GtLQeGU11iHOB5G5h@2E2tLCZq0xEuCYasAMRO12rWa8d3iq9ryeNyB98JjvXKp9v@X1SHyQMsW3MMMbkTQovovW67p1tQvdhS07ZeX5bNSxtj1HN6ChZcFaaZqKhPBAh1WEbX5MrB6zCeanOxz1q22MSjdBX3sDgtEUyqaYOK9GnayD2I2fa42P2IzLxpxtM7SsGVsfbImiOnXFWEudGbi94ZiI4kwabwjtp2w3ecXOgAiiM5@cvKnrIk57G2a/TkhdRXx6LQV4BaGp6vm3CBbHZrjnjBHfs9Vms4huZe1fMSvh64zoSIyeE41eFjFD81n17j9UwwPvquOO26IdlqqPUP3NG9IDt4JwiKIHFaWKq6VSKVd6AxPtab2S54mA/5sIYo5TOzg@OmkQIbWLfMMYds0E8Tlol9zGInLkELqLev8VAtmUJ4m5@pWJBxXc@PFNleXEIrWWorFvuTD3Ug/DpDrMJlmY5IMBBw6DNyhiocR0pFbh9AAh@lhIoqUY9CyHLtPBx2RpsXiyNz@u8BW4dYivOjgP/cqVOY0EgHfPaVRrwDuDtnZ7T2PS9boWe39oVndXCjiTMc8swcSWSsyxnF2GlkTUy8ThtD3ckQgRPaAb3rYGJFvcW2I5XGExLrGIZ1g2ZWxv3Kbf8WkOEF6tmwALjogrMxBsgohHRHN4xG2sHSxIjMuMaAU0u9pB1xYVrBzHOoPT6f1w3ArU0jVts7HTCvue1@ZICaO@hAJAfp5meYdWDnETtxbFCHCWinxvckDCBiFZSPaNOvAdC19/TRlzx/SGuMq4F2zcYFsvgKhH9SFPUkRsS8/YYWcVznkzPOwuMQTqZkCIOY7@CEQ/i0MpworGmxmCv5hdsnBH1eHxnvQDiIocjCjsJzMAS051vWSGAY@@68@pAsKkGxaBCReDBhnxkyXfCRtY8gf6i3uncJqWlj5S58YZS8xdHyE0xTYQqOsA/6Jw3lBMzgg9PiOcclx4D5e8BG@yZGm6JJWyAURiJVdnwMzNhPlmNsychqkPK2u9W3bYhlrMFtIL8QYdkHwEIaLu7wVG9LJbuU4gB0y299edoIm4TSQpqDX8GWejgY0n8w4sQeh4rjgRTMabWjdd0qjrt01Gd1HrND@8TbVuLBabX3oyUDpjQ@YS@yxTvHbxdOJP/KNnFH@mEsGroHVMRK8CepJKshtgUxqkTkmtqWhm4iZOvLxuOVmlm6hSmqiikUtWaSaqrDqRp9KJ0UUNiH78TfbM6CV8K4lHQG3YASo6XfdedjdFdkDHZhqEjEx4xFu90AyCguctZX3aofiFE7loThzbSxvmJ1/B4xvfqRcpDnlVTMY7uDdX91gMcKlE/pjdgPfSukMZTQb@Yd0/Zwwyul/rXKUXk1S2w5LhJLo9wFutdLyVzJpa6rtyaohSIRa2eNPnTAOc0qfov9cqrRvIxZGVQnCrq0UhEZ5dL5/TVlaGxcjBohOtzPwrJuBoBB2R33xlTJaBdDoxr4zktjDlc0p2EyikCzhuyRH/nyHpdZKKFSUmGupQ@BDGVCt53j1tz/iMmUHw@mMt1jpRfBpb6aGRP49avjCrRrIXc0tPLiWzysRWFUuFxwobYls6zS08f7Vh0sGGAHknxWOk24eRWJPOLMHLoZCMtRR/yM5Og5YvEipJtpjQlbrZGQI4OeQGuexEr5yYK3Pdw8llxEmsnAkmScd@IUy7eimB7ARQxknUAv3nDTiuO8Yn9txyJSmnh30eR1hYZtwfYwtb2Iz7Y2whhWPD/jhbmFiGlrRcf5IvEiMhJMClRL1jYJtSXAaZjPt4qfuJUozQ@CLuy9zrpGdgG5Oq2tbpTKlKlkQ6dEmyDf5zLwOzpB2NJtiRiHduR@Mi6i2tca1vXtt6ZNa9t1ukzVRySZDRnAxEgE6bFniMLjIImW0rkMQWI5jeM3fl7iZ7tF@WDQvvQRG16/om@bo3AdasKsXMtEJpvPdHyK/PRD43HUUh2mKtTceHt7fLNNa48BQM2iidcmac@DpPYLUSwyrZu9gIJUk8B1LuWZByz4BUiEHSE/sNrZf8uTRAnDrvKRBfvkzD4D@/0EZKwyBJ2/ZhxMY@@M4dPwVzkZStJb5T58qtMlsh0pOfgvF@EgbHBb2xp3E68caF1e0f3iCYjMoxl7JJXpmBkcVqaRqtLNBiqc37XV3OqEq8t81/a974diew9PRIix9jXRlXiW/sIdBS0qu@BRbN/9Ic@mVjw5qcD4J4wgxD2rLzO6dDHoQQC5M8FbMVYoIsuQ/VGUlCPJ47Kfx4tzrp/RgBT@dWyzzZkw9i8IkZnUrUNZFYCY4zW7hIOJnVysi3WduzJ9tfmtl@P@iTjnM1EwEu34UdX4xSEyI9Uk0nttbPWstmrmfT/YrrbROxSZ4/yV9NdX2Vuo6H6TSpe96dXv0fg6z7YkbgD2jy54ZH5iD5ciaSOGh3tXFL9UbdpjdwnjPVpUYef2SPNJ9zHWdpSVVatGXWnvFhFWtx@D5PNwk1GIwQqlEf5zWhXO7E5IaNzBMGnizbDu56XDqfQhNso@16bk@7ytcL5vUA5xe2bBbhO/G4i1vwey0idOjFzJ9fJSZ129M5uJH8CFnLs8ceXI02NRbZqCWNluia6XFyTyupcxQcq9VwqbVJRcXwDg5DX4tmrvUlUswzs01gz9GeHlOIiInnNak3vBOgH@fRtfnEHPUtKe3QPIOUs9Qta@V@hro1fq669W@g5OSAOrFvrT3oBXbtSaE2ucl3fisUbGDG7gzXLZ8au7sJhyfNsdkVdL3Bu2KxCCc4TTfkU4uENxycEvtBIVm6AJt4oX/3l8GnZgFVcWiByARr5jDTC4MOiZowHwyuJRoFcKCiKI2jCfAJjiZGtN7Ewj3AntPDq5xfQykpHnjaiq9x@vZy@6cGMx@DBPG8NfUVHUT/vqqrUU@M6HeubBk0FHPfjGpDDb1NmWtyRB4kXMGjjr2SxsB436xfLeDgY2Pzu7PAZ@DyXJDDxWe@R88QUx@9TifIqs/BoNNeTMnr0GSF3d14haIUwVVCmTwhhy/OKu/W78RCOKMIcAs6Xr4TXDM4nIDrZ4v8lmng9XGSlsY6duJdV@/76dT5LyliTOryCrq5olIXeN5znaIlKsVH6E@DlYAZhPazSnfdfrrFdJosTGugfksVfRFGb0pZVZfbwbCnbFOXcZkjnSiSEb8wQrOnS4Oos9HN/xr4vTR1HdkOnsvx028eXu7JnOKWuKkv96Ur0LAoMDROCNHzvBoPZTid@uP/g3UblgM8bmQbr30SG/M3Fu@HMcZjZqnb4dUVTS@xxG8aV2MGHIvKXIlvKYA0emAH3t8RqyC9fBUuS4AVXLWpj3utBCLnqxdZtTwaXv20TBD@pT46Zgbq6Uf0xLWJv@ZoWu@OOI53JM/YDIcLFNNyBxUuUcFxXrY2/n6XrlQq6kV/ZUVVKlv0kcupylZF7SBha0vt0O8t/H61sfruXVluzu1kvlPilkl8UFsEg5egFdoI7NBPytvAjgpbKQzxi8LGi2z5xeXG@mY5LJxXti4KhWv6@ud//vc//@t/ChX943/xY4t/nP9iC@Xz@cKL1vcXrx7K@H2@c7H8onn@on@xfF0Gl/0f)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c)</sup>

### Explanation

I compiled interpreter without `SOCKET` defined.

l33t code is on the second line:

```
7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55
```

Unwanted operators before main code are cancelled by making them parameters to FWD(5) and INC(7) operators.
"Words" in l33t are sequences of adjacent non-whitespace characters.
First two lines before main code as seen by l33t interpreter (with calculated numbers):

```
(7 20) 0 (5 9) (5 11)
(7 0) (7 28) (7 4) 0 0 (5 13)
```

Last operator before main code must be 5 to move pointer to zero cell.

#### Other languages

Last `2` on the first line is for Del|m|t.

To avoid printing trailing space in CSL Enter needs to be pressed at the end of the program, which cannot be done on tio.
I slightly modified CSL interpreter to fix this.

Fixed output encoding problem by suppressing Thue stderr output.

Answer (score 6):

## 157. Haskell 98 (Hugs), 7177 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rb@vKlhj4@TDzD@YLt@x7JFkPknrLtry3npZsWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQoUiap5z4@6MwMOunuYCa56TRuupO@tzsZTAOTD0FmBkiQAANMvgb5EScfG4O5/@DOWkXqZcve@3RPgKEtsli1atWqVatWrXqywxv93/3uAC@6oimLnqKZtCkaJt3V5amo@@nUgv7Ey0Y4EKQohErqvclIVE3jmDqgOZqWVUHuwjttakNRlZeiDv4Bmh7rWk/nR7TZ501aNAR@LBq0NjHHE5PWpP3RgjSdHWkD2YcxR7LaAzBT1Me6aJLwEE03VIUfdbr8i5DwiwTHOoQbdEZUfhj9YNKCNhrxatcAyAhNZ8qpbDH5AkOUpq803RARjyAahoaeMZqeZ0XhBWgcQHld1orJ0vmLII6lz4F0fqyIc5rvGKbOC6asqRjE0bVSo1Z5GSNAN@u53EvfIH3p01Q6NxGGO0GkDCq61p0IyB@zL0Iw8lSSFdGgBMj7GT22S9KPDvqA1kW@a4FRkqbTGIUeDRVapoXxmO4ofN8v0IoMsDk2RotYBPQSwpW@Qc/HI9qQR4DF0EbiNi0GrYpilzbGoiBLskAooMW5KaoG5Njw0zLQPpMVhe6KCkTYkCV4ARk9Mba8LCL8VFejaLiE8YtMrN8ORYBRxRUjxDGUBDJCw4IDrqz4MdP58RiIBGbWgHBTHoH8yabToEXekFHCIYohql3Cw/Fa9jWaV7dzSU9lnuaB3olOcBuijgXqJ3jpvqiLgJJfS59rpssmsABZnKQrIq/TdV0U3bv1YCdJSEzDFEzMiJ8U4empM1vOOaEorRh@fmxSB3qwfn1B8bQ/QR8@nsAv4XCcUNlShv58eI9uS@yhuMe6i3fTiR9pg7m/F@E35zpMT3@mACsFXFFoRhubDO8bA4E@EwhkeHSiyzcN@MfKVsL06Yuy2BIwC6oLpUEXVLrpJTkTJrqOVXvDVH4ImVY0tQf8hMzqExX5odIRFopA0KBmemlxClwDkSdlpM0Ih@t9GQrNwCLZqkyWgiIMBRUFsmdzdJWuoSkTAgcxDRMFELgCURFjQaKbtMTLCkaBcERlUa2LxkQxMc5E7WLJgwISu356RYagdRFopE0hOR6QEg@oT6OtWkiIAmAoCI1kFYN@@od/1u31AE9SEDS9a4trk@5qAlGlPCEW9BONAqupvELIAjgvpm5FhwSmvCJ3eROTVxd2EoQIkupMmyhdWoME9ZkMVavPT6E6SpIomKIl5Jb29dIjfmjpDtmSXMj4iO9AwZIESNok2z76UxpKSRCpAyIzvtHElGK0b5ylnQbznevjsevjh3sRiHP73UeHDNM7AYHzHxEveHO@JznN5I52NEze0OQuNV6YfU0N0D6BdggJbSyqLucODqfXqXecbj/qNJf7RE4IfklWuy7nKcjiGSTsdJ8ICeFOPn44eRF9O0lAM0M0WF1Fl@B2UKBySKWYMiNeVv3jBd302a6tMM14RJZjsH/LGxnz0m9qeRyQ1gflUkMBAT3kNxRRHLtYP@dGNYFwe/ONAfty@gKHneFj@cHjPHB6trNOMEBOdzKKlbUua6i2lHEfGxhgimqMQX3rKLsCD9JjoBY3wQTw0h0i10T1g2YhOnEmOnWR7oAiXckRqZJWlcP4PlSUNoZNFVrB7dZosbtVoUEZQJ02jVdaWdFmkDChDdswUCEqJs73oIggspWhpJUhK0Xis5u1oQqKBbF1RDrm68hQGbDagW63ZX8rjwAeDFgwgM2qLFs6aMQvAItgtYmbikPLEtSpEagJfUELIuoeUEKi1bBgIhNSDw0wftAMYn2BcHi3rr2qaqbOJH23oKyXzLs1CjO/XalQ4dCSOKMVXu1N@B7aXypE4QVBHJu2woKcGCaopJftDvH02Y2o3@hTh59epk0aE7t53UoDlb1VenaTyKOWsS0wnwJKleZtG5LuyjqoJ2XxMnUAmL5I3PE9guwQ8L3jDRJWlgAImTgXhYkJ2g0EedaXhT7ILlKnWvrRaoxeJg9e26mDhvdJ66SRGO7s2wDlZ9ZeSMabKHxYoq/xQCOLqM52PEjhb3u8j5k3RnsQa2sSoUHY8vUzvB9k7ws4R5qq7UEKjFyjRZDdEKscwCKroTUIDdjK/CKVdW0irosIygy0B9R8kL@@aY6NY2gvZLM/6fhBUpi6viiYZRWFhTH1hWxqlrujaB1QzwbUT2aVAiNMOvL8RYaI37oMBwY1BUNMMugEtOBPE5A6l1MyQHES/zQCbwU5iAInKKy7AwAJkB8Y5ZIMopJzoFRqC1VwOfykKvmh0jm8tAMrrsMNDoy15ktaG6EWolvEQECLL6WD5pJAW9m6n6h@fm@Tt24DiH3ndPoHmqy6Pjs/fPjgPHaegYb/8OEjuE7R9RFdHnB9JC4fcSGcH10khpe4MPSOxEC/B@fz3Qrz3P2AxTbH1mkpj1383fFx8MHL33H2M4BPN6g60GwA7cMH4HG6Ewl0ut2Osxlk1N@RdnOfRu1cE3R5bDPhgp/y1rvNhSBhgzwaazoasifY2L7Pk1FCh9YQjFeh79Kd93fs/cP95/uu5/7Z6cXY7hM@0YFMQXqukb@naxNoNt13oWMf9@B23wWhsewknKzzyOWK@RRIiHe7fxFze3iL2y6nCFrbdX/vBKba/LkT@jrBN/cG3O41q4AObKDBNnQ5/Z9jkH7H/eD2OCGu2@mFrkbC6QTOCMgEg2QaJZMwKAcCmK4Vd7p6oyGoR1owFLQpfLplVsArc2R5dsljbTod0wXSsqrQXgIJ0Fx2110cVVN96oQYwsRK1bYTIp0xhCB@2HigYpR3YBCxJM/B0oeKu1hZNNgAo1GThu6epoj@FrExHDRIPo311b/XrKlY7YJfMDaFCAYMOMcKL0DN3EV376DvASEIKsPsD3GfvEL80uYh3ZMv5RFaBoFXkX9dmZjfE9noI3vBRMI@gS4BV9H2hsZdJFwr0AI02j3gtDiXTcsYB0GoYZQ8b7jcaP4lLfMJrTZs8pGoVdedtMeaAB0XEZp@DLV6gXRWncq6piKT/VlADRJ7gmXwAvk@9oIYJZOFQOZt/u5DDhx75c1t8XYb60vmCoZAM6qmaD2NPgIAFE2/3xZsqBz1/kSkRKGv0Y57aEICZzTTFacMCqQDdHUfbCEf2BuiTlrbdTR78IYytQk0211RkUeyWSCjGIqKbdNG765C01AAGwQVWTQp26DcNFc4oLFRJWrPgs/OUeMYlEiedKmcyT5WkvV8wsFMDJ1R5A7ksCs@jsCyUETDQdMHdFWE2HaE5VCpapqZIJUUx05eXwcItIIvZh6LhVQ1WW1byZB4hjyaKDwmZsHXyLtFYGF74EXStdHaijJs3h4GkZvizgAadi3s0BCGTuzhsy3/KPqPcOjLL1A9QaB9mvW69rQBYwiIw2F@YTymeh4PQpLhsbWnDRknKHGIzK93Vp6fOfYZ/dfjY1u26jbGfeFvR1oj5whyQ50Y463MfeYCxH9qShIq27V3kHgPfYAGrCzC4T3DgjZ4BGG7WkdU5pGQT1Qkvzlf@tGAiYQo60H7um9B7IlLzZf7IlAmWCO@ufQigNcpi8I6qIyiBuqhKBtkFHVbKKh1O3RPOVaN6U6b6diEBDadW9o33d8rd2wjIvIJEjXU0IbbuB6hBxpGLGsUo6HyOqYEmpTcdkBfEfU6xKoXo45EbnsAju2OHlRyHHZErlzgoBX2NTVo18QZASMmK0EG3JJVnqmSBxqv@@jZNcN3iOmI0gRUPgM2Bbq/AOaLxwik1OnIb4ECX5D01XMPmD7p7GMbyFf/VU@N3mG8OdFNRezaz//0e10ogNfF0@cXpJlbOx6Bb0Q2pDdLy46KL@S2v2QJzGCiyDxhA3F9CaXA4yAZr6wd@1GjPqZ9vj6vQ@EuVoULwok3qOzvyJlFuS4qk664eu5PhLB4tz9oxVblEckRPNEcIubtG9Ff9Gat@MSgUDS@S7BYzb4sbkrbKhdxzvcgc8yWUgKV@hV0rjqd9Ga0F3pX5sS64wDvl8pVHuNvP1eOd4WMDfMdTmQ0g@/Ib/ARyYi8JdlWhcH@kE9S@KHlfETn/sxa2dHlXg/6gfbzLTDo9JuiMQbDh5mRxztisWo9aNLK8@/h1BXr/hbIan5r7XgLELKqkNvPET4iDgLUEJQdnGbxbbFJfsFYhe8ssCfT//lShAmSZhmUTELweNggttDrYbnNhM54/HZ8NClI/Hh8f2xr7ocgEDRJEsUv1VxofeQRr/gC3S3nm4p41c/euPaADqAjCma0whsgJKbNZnEKxUJu7wkuNigCisvG9Y7YbshZjb6@NYC3iTOWBU2RjTEp7tXLWxrx5dDHBg3O8JHbJiq@veZvFzoN2Fj71q79lVoTTBxEe0OOvkJJWeNXOEK4JRh@7S3eCdoMf2@aCX1tKlr3/Q3Xci9VX6GCfAqRDFnYE70rfElccTqG3PZzcbiXKlNQ9vof01eapvdF1aADfnbV4ccxcOj0WwNq9UL5bZk2ZEUzoGeB9/d4AT0Iw7Du@6V5m20yr/rIsMa2e3@0vUSRRo5OkvsbhcsrPU2JxHoMD7c3JWCiS6jp7efXari1huK4L2qotdGjqZz9fFO1D@H/S8JBhlJ0HDPdcr5jS@1TZ/ZY29sZhK4BToTsz1yOjZGYfsbq9r1VALrQn/GL1fNv0Hq8xd1V6zFeEJMZbDqMEI@Bw9QtM/pvklro/dS6X6ejXqGNfikTW4U7VETQ2OT@qkjpAMv9zBgcy369xpKUiTgR92qQcmcg4rqSd3TH1xPF2tk4tIdAGGAeDoCsoZZ2h/CrqMb2HN/eVTi8IkMl/6I1s1fVjMHOHmMfugKOCjpeR@ypk/FO4W7xrjpRq@9zrj9e1Wytu0MkhvxcjRT7ss20Y4obIvm9ZbZnRxp0e7UR2BDqV5S/jZSMKVn3HcTEZ4N5IOP4m/4u3mN6PbkC9ivYI1Cq8tDw4SDe1ymewFv9dQIcj0OPTBXNBd7f4vY@RdrRNOXnlA7o066MZhoYn7iK6kul9Mr2sefZ6M3IhIGjHB3prTEJq62xO4/APewov1nQFciSSRqHrynlV4OG77RaW0OIX@pDQotNBn4MXVi536K3ipWb88f80XcJXg2MMSvHe8ji/uDX2EfjldFLhpBx2NkaaN5MDBy80D/jBXBK7voMoS@ORPL6jsXPdwcTY/V4E2iu4W9PsJ8hY6xvxBvLUOFVvO8Mam@ZRKamigZj8npPxL6KIvJgjVq@bynZ1dDtXuYWRnxPzH1RsjbDDrgCg8x2bTn3D0AcW5OiAkT7ghqxuoGaOhQXxuq531heCFCek9G72PZVcgFHN79Yq/3M3uHqL9h8al/rq32xr5OasX57q26ARJrWitL3MgH093ljiEtOiELa9PH6xjZ3FU1Rvoa7qBAt9ahp@wdes7jWswtRfxbeBd@BAPvxxTE6aLcJk0gD/lbd6YsTaJ4MzdTGoo@8vQWq4AiPdd8/llwoOw26JYt615puw6E93pQ7ikjPZCBhYGxPEOwfPeooGo@rmt6x4IEzq@fXjEcJmv6lJqHHa@Z4TB6PY2VikBsZwvVJ@8cmj@kcIfRrZEE2rYlOS2LFntYR@vKXCq8j8qYqDxm79tuv@6V8VxeTjMu0L4PefkUGVukLP8pAYju8ho/C/novF@114u8aI@mJri@@rBt2pyjXw6nWJAA63hqMseed9gSTZh9n81ez1u/MRNjTVG8KFDGk0Wj2iSxYJtybQ0M7Kw9sFijBoPkFLgmaMPyiLfHmYKU9q4msEuStuVfwfzmi8T4ZeVu9Qc/QlZ/0DPd78NaMWZWsNF6vRTO89hJp8JN1e0GssV51flBQBV0kK9NWK5XoA1wvN8EcmJrupwmcy8V7PG43ZUXCgaGeCmArKLLuF9cCWkuKDVqRDZPAyhJ9d0cffp4fs8fcM52gHccO@uHBwkpWpWXnY7Jgt2pFvTvkHxKHTp/Peei8V49p1klARQX66XtB@R04SSYPi85N1mmVt9YioHuV0xNrjaPRJ@uIobZ3QWs0wNAkkqPp1ko9azloHWeT/uNfde3l1WBZGPRINqBf1lNxS4A2Evva7KOVrp16cjzmcXk24pj1USVh6r50kjZmqF6sVdXajG7k6jF7jaa9cQFeKlgPtqiwChVtXFygYVqFZlHT1URLLOyE17FWmRI0ZTJSQZ93zb7hp2syWXsx0Tcz6uBCMNXUsVHreukC3RVxHJ8sqSF2nKJpQ7K4DSn5j39lrUwlC2tAhNC9Sp6sTN9KEdfPcGQ5qCBoE6B6hWQp6poN4kImgy0xwS4SCLVo@btxuQlZMguS6FstGMVkrEWj6WSN9mVpJ@6swGVoJ7LkOkxWz5t37EPiR3rEiP/p9xj3Z5tvjl/4ohHD4aVXICfPKFfbwWEI3oQ6acfh3GFnC9fwkyXra6GyN/e40E2Ka7UAdESW/xO5E2dkAShZlKGiqYTr6lUD6ge8uglqq9IkDl0Tyx731Uw6jNtPwMTlwWVtGCDLaXAxI0Y5nNM/0H2UFZ9Ac2EW3iyGKLh@dpRIreZig9sz5kxG7EzI1NE04A8EEyQ7h4@J0zPi0sWuhuvZ7767nwdY3/08mn1gjBVz7u/nv2ADN8A9DUyFw28ZrEDZUubzof@M/eEHg1/QDsez88RaQQC1/PBzpVDJ1urJeqMG3Hy2MnuQ0/QRv9EUKAtklU5fU8hGAWCLLovGl7XHWoOs3wDc5aIPefoUtyW53dT2YhQCarPa4XMcWs41CNjM27G/EH1ffEPcCn8NYGsmSaZtLUpXiCDZMuM0tjWodyVbWC5Y3cGyWXMEl3PsUYWERw46AVzyAZe@kkf061xaJfiReEAxfplR7@PYhwJ4tYF4DYBMWqeF@bXCrcztzfzz/wc5HkO79rfNMcHxbo4R4r0cA@AmGomRSxaKjWp2NxKI02ZXGPRLdNwgKJG6Ze0vsaRLs7cyrDQTMekNe8nyWrca9FQ2iMmP8iZhywC9ZlIdyQyygdrFWuBIJxUDNHm3C6qpszBRs4FK95OFQ9bqIZ9KOw6AWf51Q@ulHRTCGonXS9pBc80E0GLfW5EPCRzBbFB79uDci8xP//DPrH039ya4/8B2z9kUvP2R/SaB@x@sQjgO3v7R@i0Ab7@03r5jkJWvNxlYuVkzERnYLFRog/RKkEUjfr6Ve2zbsO2UVbCL5RHwekpYh@BWtjac2eBx3TWB81BcwHZU0qiXSXqi/uDCJeLHDIOmCI4j@ckaFXFu9UnIivGnCe6YgqaEiYQjIQ6MctE3XSEkqz57uCjCQuh2H4NUUlN5nPi@I9Cnp6e0wxB4RUxETiyWM4f8d0HH92tCDwGWsqyWOxriQJRNDAg7s6O5DnkP58aoWDmdnJN@OAGDxCpBaNNcxAEgbvRWV8siodHUbFaBeKji3CSKf7GyxsAUUsmqPNHaN7dC5ANEFm7c1/NSyjdLH3BV2Jbc@7eLwdFCsBqCHTv2Cdndd/S9ea8@2Pu7aBCY3@wRORXcf7hn09daepKvdxu5Xu4VwtzQn2qqhsthckAt7QowgSDDRdxbdcphowJ6sQb9ACihzkAdFER5oI2NZDpbuChXaq92yxBI50swJ@08O/Xc@/zeu4e1w/lC6ldMTeWY2lUqt2LlNlWbEWWE2AwrvyRzX2ovKX0j9Za15uR12iTgVUIc@7WIyRCOL0dmXl5j34QyW4Bpa078Vaou9@fnu4fTs3v14FXyP@zbSXjgP0LhAte9QfYROuk9OqewWklTxy3jhn@1OjPg2OyTXa9gtd433m/vd1lvQN9selmt2aHIauX1YmXK/8ZqHsi7n7GSIjs@LMJW9IKuWZHKIambBAXq1azANjW0nZfXe@XtRblrJpWtjizZ0Mer0IfRZcGCNoiCtrq7ZPcZdHgK5qaPBP0u7NeTruCCdHtAVaz7412ZjGfy@mpB7TqkJo5kX31FDyqOzSYWe/dGH/KmyJ0TPnE3p9eLU9/by@E3xopsunBjydyP3UnIjcuNGeBOcWfG3H0af7A3wdCrvSoest2lMgF@VbQxvenCZ8SVqwq9ODozAeQgBiJ9MRkBnEQeVRFbCZEuaT6IDHx0roi4ww0edh78o24YUvf3xXlX7kFL43J7QSX9guM2G2V43OmhOkEPW6w6x6UT24z5WZt7tjjG3/F@We2Kcxeuuz9@QO6Av3PWmjrdjlcyQHYY2Rtuui@3Gq2UBW/atXazTeeFQojH14pgt@7E4/6@QeHiYeiBQIo1Uy@CE9pQlzTix7RrQvZqGbSfJq@ue5fqNUzdTfvOsD2b0Srt8ZC@CzxIgJ8mMSXikhUcknThFmcXk4ByRl9D7eJjKY/pO87vfwA3ScRNH@LoQxrMDey3uykwTSHKMUELDTD8HSNFM@ilIUXW85AkS5HdFgC1N5hU5F6fVEDgBck1ffbtZuvCVg20uBqPH9ulsasO4zSIxekejQFo96i5lW0K/LWXfwLXUIkBVBo6pTIolE@XoqpCfXWBzIygdtL8BIRMd3tXZ3V4N1u3SQoHFol5ez0pELq7pTvr/KxoYM8cMiekB3zyDO3@9/fY8Et2079g/lvGz5x8dh0qiQUDxpj7zHXYT3Ce4JHHc6geuQ5VNEe@/RY7zs@HYO08@h1@xxyAfIeK@wTkGayjxKF6csifug67icARiQGvHo/7M0T40WD8nw/5Z@bwW7AmvOCjW7XTdWiQXVas3889A31YQw4ZL8jMZ9xtRE7awOQPZY8HafAfPiIBPzL3NQ9pV@5rDOmjn9hGLtMbrdTIrq2yLolXJ4dYDLS9j9caPUy2BlhTho8r4O0N3XvC9tlHv/vdAReB7tbHSNCleT6G2ROPM8ydOA/og08O5sihOz7fZ3xTWvQ57yQ@7H96qAwrlRv3vYuO086DdNnBhRzf0fHAEUMdMEfsD1GG@f7778EOpe/O/Gf@B/edz/lw57J6UlH6LBo98kZiR95PzsdN1y1Ku12BgBu4dU@H6fsozx95QoFP6gmExPEK0hw48R6DH0eHw3QWr//8v//nX/3nPyZ/vyK/fy/L8tjoduGn9ekhvYRrKNH4T9zL7pabR3dHWrrAwAe7L4Ey@Q1cXMXpDAedte9wL@PHD/BH/uFav@L9A/GxvQnI6@sDTR2cCQfLA47jDhbk7xHd3Hzr8s3fvRiOC9x/g@fURD58@gY4K3rIdXz8acNCxhGNOTSN@PQhhTCtHdDd8lb/eO7DizpYHQvAS3Ue/@h6B/@qJv41h82hrzmsCviXGuLfVQf/ikv82xAVS3ipgx8TCc@7F73Hz@9/XLmog@9Pv0/8LS7MFnUAvaKDs7OH52eP787/nefkxP4HfXKyfsPLcgEBDx6f5/Tu9NR/djY/8z2c3VEHn6mD@TN1EHCA2N8fUQeJ@WmVUHmXOVvlZucqgs@p7@GuUgSDvu4NnPoOArlk2huoNVIHHLyFN68YGMTXajaZKTcAulLMJmvZ80Iz26iAv/HwePbpk8cPJfQJ@HP2ABTNf@E58yRM06RvH4/89Fdcj3tc1it1kDmbNxjfKRBdpA6qJCWf//Hs4Qfq4O7gzuX56PnIKuyU5Ybc8Eorb/7L5TkEyHN2oOlsn@1zXRBfmhUb7IJdzNmRVua64BThjx2BU2alOdtjVVbluFA5Uv60g@3t/1FZuyprgE@DuOacNRE1K8GzVy5fAUYJUh/An8yy7BzInLNT@GcVjlzfPbKQUTd7f0/d0Y7vRdBCfs7pZ53@iNMpP4Qj46fPz4HI0x2xVsLxhzvcO/ngoL3Ox/s70DHOh5MDxri/ZywV7QiEHCdkf@Xz8@NjJllPPj4yOM4zPz30fPL4PsGVOPOc2o@PB92zk4/3xz6UbkvC/Y8HzOnH@7OgD90RDzA8AH6njOdnXhuU8PxwTzlds1arhb/WbDqzXMRh@d231qF4azHgZbnQCy4EZfbF33XMXwuYy3UXfvj87Ha7750nTnunsosmW5Ud3P08INEBB1rOrrgbGk4uiOZZJEy7z84iYfCIxNw@F4uWtRXl3jEej@8dfjKW4CdL5hKJpK7zC@w/uEKAxBUPJxL3Dl5/vHfcBR4wbtgXj9Ca7osH3Q63@zvu9BTSwCQCbvB2OOcOTXfSn5@3/1yfn09d5HLjn9uNnm4QGPI8c7sAwB2Gt/lnF33qOnWhH3hhvM/PZ@gkcJ/BdedyP7ifny0/uLvcpxbWMzcwjoYG@r/SP@jz///8XzVoA0yA5wO0BlU6FHa7OgvRHYq4Yp64/Zf4AIx1OYLOIHDc4eSdd3efjoJH0dDdx4cj/xH@XKf3Zw97Wj032CBQl1dVL8EdYMFSB/6TqoMLOJxYFU8Ee2O2ovXoYPwEjYUT6gCiOeA6gJpCQ2Gena7Fd9MYus@w7GlSmrT7gXY/fwaRtgLBWnTZEy7393MW9Qrtpk86icPPB/zzCcFPPztW4HbNIPhdzhMyI@f47Djk9TvuwfHsOPzceUaz@ohzE@stHDo5OQpZ7mgM3NyR2xpkBvPrZO2GENHghRNUQScHKLlOYKIbcpXoiD1ZBVN6u2p6wuHwByYAj/kvItnA/Mi@zo72XLFAzHPk@XR3BD0MLIoH4vvDB@oEp7usuTWHz2FVcDoWJ0Qc0IYRp0HVnoqHFc989XeUObJcHP6yHwwKeoQd6OXP6CgLPX4FdzRpkvTB8oeuLd0RRehdiIqy2skPHSClO5O74gfqAO09MC4NEa5RhRcnojibTGbi@krLxjE/GPBjcv30m9//6Tf/w09/8cuf/uL3f/qLX/3217/6ffj9Ffx@aT1/@a/iYbz/9tf/6H/@6c//Ajz/Pfz@Hfz@7W9//U9/z/qR9/8Av/9zy@8/2L8tOOtHAa4/@u2v//gvf/vrf/Cn8Pvn9u9PX/5@@pN/Y/3/X/YfOv/ipz/5D3izX37/l9Rf/@vf4P8f/@u//ne/wf//5V/89b/@J3/9R/@SOP7Mcvzf//xfWff/8nd//7/8d//4v/zdX79x//1377/@Cv9f/1fw@Xo6vwbP1@Tr5/r8@m9Ez9@GG5tUQKB@9Yc//dO/D3L6J@j@e@CGf9rjsy6PDfAH6PnDIcuCBXb/wzbkDwwHZhHNbHn@Af3DPS6T5zaQgP@f/cCwYL6xFuQa5zbkH/721//4L8H3h080@NmQf38V3dY3O5BrOrGHYaX1BwD851swf/DTb37vp7/873/6zZ/99Js/ojgaD/H8QH@gAjQ@8YaexEFc8yMqHAS1tnJzG3cwRNxhuO@zgnE28@OnHS8L99E@YAL4kYR/2GtUYxpHK9r2JfZhFX8vho/0JwiGJoi0Qqd4xxfwSUH3xe7FJM5idILy0rEEdOtTCJiAdxKOTvIODRYeDJqgMisIms4AP7A1m8@hH/Q9/f3K/8wCpc8o@kcCbaNJWIh@pMDTjv8jQZvAOPM5RbDhv238oRt/q4DVjbxStsfcAp6/8qAgQ14SnYrSjQrcqoXzfH3rWc8m03kqQqfKpcyLR9gGCtPFbK6@fo1aoauo4TWKdrZYfPlqP9ra8XHiRy4UpeAJbxM8cAVbGDyqa05O0/RDJ/IUhP2OffgcigZC4VA4EIxEwtEAF4rEQ5FwLMhybIQNBwJcPBSKx@LRZzpOUWeffaen1FktWwdE9TLNBVg/dXZDz/10pXLte6bOoN/NBKgzOsGFoyeLBKCzPHAoM2E1sIvPPsOgKGx7P9DhqNfr9/vhhk8vucjTf/jdCoR7uzt44OBYLuxwRNhA1OGABtb30UEvRLpPj@ggfTKGbFNXOKMX56ylWDLiBJcuxnHxCbTYM5Ws/engoXGT8due8EAvdOpyr2/S5kxbAxiGAV2NdSdk1QFZd0RadIfn8fdzL0hB3L7M9z1MKw3i9ypEeQ1O5cFwGeHRL7gQ18RxLVmiWcqPBRUIxGPhWDwYiHlj8VgozEXCYS8X8HLRWDTOeoHzMS4SCwNrvbFQPBgCQfGCSITjUepAVLuyxDBH1AHncJCnrAp4AsApHqWg@ftn1EFXlHCdEj13dd30QXftMYnRjmDsnqUhooOLULhm4GiegD4qrqYIcjTnoBw8LdAHuVyazeUcjhS@QIvAplmHo4sv4RjLRlMOh0hC0iDPAYjUx7dshMXtVA4ZX9LJXA4xDPAlEEMcDsfQCrFelNVLFMBUfAkGEQHtcDyt0bGAXLMoipFYpvXCsqm0wzGxyIvBH8AlrbcQITaLLxiAkXJWSBrCHI7zVSRo6ByOqgVnJ5Vf5TeZdDgK1ksyiSguSObDVqYu8SVJLoikwxtIr8PRA0dPB6vU4eiAE2XY4RDAJSx48BuBC7cfqCbvcCysfGBOHI45geaFocPxuPKHdICefJ7vm12xZ10L3XoKEFSAIHk@yeY65@edXq@jL5LZ8yoJurjI84PFRO/0OnbEziNcGsaCoOFo8fISMejxkVf2B11CkPoi6HHxKBIKH/knoMy@epjQ6PECgy4gaN9IpI0QrhEAd/BKjeCZ4jtW0OoiQeQ573QcJyC0FFYfeuFyfybjLy7akJciaB0X653E3L7wx0nMEYk6jo/g6fjoCIJz7qJZJ3S@HM57h8N9F3/46IiGHcfOjx99zm@5j7QjGnccO6JRB@0@0UVzoqt04OQZ01km2BN8PuFpaTTvxTuebeT@bMN1Tp5R/ULP7/OTa@lJcN6l@yMS5oK@ZcjhPgZCT54Z5hSrP1ZXeNIrlU3mngAu5vCBfqfXAJaeWNdz2ucDNU7DD2wiDB8nrDy7HHEX9lSBoHj83kH6ltasgMvpjAacTrfzBJB8IOeZ0RadSDuhb5V71PKQ@3jAscq8K@6DLjftiwPlr2jRh8eGyes4P0SSOqYdkbgDvfGctvirVuST18d5j4864dOzv/Pq@m/@zr5rvy9elNXKRTjq4Jnq4hkCoTh9gj31z9Tz5@fTs1Wql/RiwXt8q9dvabrnOaQOncgDZ3B3PCqZSPaqyVUXPJmmDnxBLaQdHB4eUgen9TNH0FH2P64H284YMlx7j2O5OPbpv388/eD5G43E@fxnn1aDzkA6Q@kiLpjs4lHY1ohYLIyF0qONA8/f8IJEqATgpE5wIMNxgLVPULQJjvLT91aGTn88ICNmdOWzNFHJjPnxFc6PuvjjGjnY5e4B5ObHkqx8jgV9Z2SGCeX6mQiGUCbzANSBqtlO4CN0xk1xbkI1CIcdKHVQZONa/Lvod7HvrhrlRjn3iT2OHccI0@/vbVnxck7OSYrx8RO0dnI1Sx3QP2hh7kf14uTgeOwMhpzBdcndJw4sNnFR98FZIOo3@MXBg71O3BUCzwdr3jDAHbR2r9nOy5QMzFMHsavvsVeyOolZDhAXw9D04fPpM/yfPd@dnj6f4ooreOC/dXt@tsLJP5K2eiGPzbUDt4HZhP/NBMn/ePDwo@/U@j/FW7psMcERCTvcB98nzqB4je8ev3s8ADUTpx0BUigexhr6GONJ@HgdqeRPNI7w77uNxxFEP1q/iadHBh0@g64K@DEMc@@@DoBFE49HYpED6nfAsHdWvUDoehpYEkXdmIz2zQMndfmKxzlydT0XDI6ryRIPfPy0Om57ZfrQaPvgQgc0frb9bHtoy4ucUr/rtzAYXJWLvmA843nm5JMJtIR61oVjgyZZXUkf4VYk3Hzgpj5T3wCuiWCSBb1wO6Gob3BlKb66VnBe@lvDdGPvi3VT33xjtxqG6TfMR0SOkWxPH3dCPVPIHr7bNWhy3CUOZ1s7Fnhcp6mNrQ27yoK2Ihmk9bOsOLLZANPdIviIliwqIDdHNEmRUI6Zs5L/xgLrTCQkJVcoZiEO9OIkstTDju3QO3gYLMneB8ltJ06z4IVYEJxwioAjIKADTxfB7R7htgjBRSA9NIfhElkyAlBg1HoJJV5asiPe4esDREf0EugqAxBbqbusHNBHj3aydh5WjTFmAliIuSOtHWm09Z7gtUsPD7K6e3DTn1eLr10YCt3owGZ1uI0LCsP6kAOJKIy69sGWiQ2bCTbuwQtFe2It4nWt4WyfDaOeqSPTOzqximp8Ql26BPdnXFJw8uPo22@F78Z3o4cT9yhh4tPjGUHTO3TJFsiRmRglQDzGd/LDiXnn8cgPiZH70oXveH4sC8CSxWzDbecNcq4mgBZcdmS4vcs71fej@uDN3akeIHniPbpNLL18gvXO4SeD3aJ4nxKcnQ9I00wsPeoJfwo/XN2ws0Aa7A8Pf7LjhVGGLiWxvOMfEsAPBSJ6PDnIDNBp3Ckez4MbElcg8HXEE@Xbb3mPcjY/UXw@N0J9F/yYuzPB8eBJ4Puxiz@df1zeTSD@sQueCUhGcQPxEM/m9fOadqDvBHhslemGdIvGOZI3B/JGicTR7cej26PEhw/Lu7lv9OC12H/MbqQBiZ8j8SdbC9BdR7du@gVLyCi/y/EL@fgXflCODq/s8QCTveOtmBaFR7cQMvZ4VlQ/o74kx8uvVs6ghNmLpq2TMskReWQhHDm01CDn4ppd3D4CcZOGIMs2uLXvZyxDT5rH7WhecmgsTyAwzP7eBQbezz9@pFZJ2@t0IWVULh2R5rFHTk4713HKgXw7xdp59yX9uk8Nr3Tuuh9aK9xmaejzBiNb1ZWoJlLhDF24QxBUA5/Z5xNLY1mrs0HZEO0BMER7IJwPtQgyydYTNmTCDoTSWhUQxEI9IVm7RvGERQP1E1rI65oPKsQiAyrzHjJk7yBBdBPIkwwuWj4l6YEDqgr1DWQCacA8yA/0GSgy@ttvafv1NAHd@Ci2BQiGcAMPh0CvKIXEv4JSwIFUDkBGUR@SRIC2bzAEdx/sJBT62yVkbx5yQQTPwGvtIfKTPUSuiWpYW@eQb26LDCyLb74ZeBIhmyD4J10PiA9hz787sJv7Yzpdvqo06tnqVbIGd@g5xbbPhV59e@HVietjPEm9I6tkBb3AVzmxfSHQtAuMWRPPwMNPq3Tpi0aRDgRKGS@eWAOsP7AG7KBBPV5jEg1yGqjh1/QeM5OHMrP7ISf8CgZZrE8@G@VbHSCN5JDGWdls6Nvs5zNwNAwac/uYjZ2zmkeiYdgHyftWH@ch@5zJ1sYR7tCDWmgfPE/WQa6WcpGFgzgr5iXLUXW5J5MvrvQtBDvxyQHDphWd1A8KD4zv8iaPEk3FYyx7TLNedHArR2DlCK4coZUjvHJEVo7oyhFbOeK2g1th5izM0M0NBiMbZ3TjjG2c8bUzxG6cGwyhwMYZ3DhDG2d449ykFlqnFokRvPTBipuk6oo6hnGh2CoMN@RClwY9w4CGe@kZAkIDryAheuiVJ6QX2/WMxlk7oQJTRqBAILJ5B@2zgk24LKq8Fh1eK2XrzfaEtoqyOm9EYLO6DlopO8cvZIDQuY9p3KBEUaB2aUEReTAGRBOslEQO5F90H1sbd/XF8WaTEmJIcOt3iI7HT0McjnzsxRKfPcGBfcEWtsBebNbOZ3rNmK0dXjaRFpXHOy2thTG047eN9QMqWOToGxABCwLLYHdL2CrNuj7Zm2Tw/SR3EO5N8hVRFt7wvljIGxdBnlhFJe0/wZZYpWfZKSIpbTAD7E97ERl4UaC4gzvxmTt2/PbXf/q/0r/99R//Bf3Tn//F//Nv/yd0/xu8/W9gs9CBNcAv/xhv/wxv/wRvf463P9mKROCDx46f/vQ38Po//kv6p9//YyvoH/@lwxtaI4IQ9NrE/NXfw9vfx9v/4fCG14C/@kMLEKM4vM/UjmnlAqhf/nuahtQQyxrZn/4VTTs8YGC4bMm7s@r4w9Z@TwvBmg13xPXwMty644cRgMes2@MAvPYbt3nzYAG4t5DrPH6ralP3wJyxdg@glhZ4oY97@mwvzUD7R0ATRjP8PZC3WReMHnsQwwm5/7v0Me30IIwb11d2sY9DdLidfzvfjk0ownocDFCHR8fbqMhnI9aUQPeWAvkmPYGF4cduC@mRcpaM2Pwt4bfwVg2IYyVZ5BR9yk5rFRs6PbT9RSHyWYVVVxeFFpsha@M3@ZoAZW8647YS3FE3L4oNUnnpA13GzVbQ7ajEQxyNoUgg2prfyFh8IVzwvkS3KTm72mTLuRcVBq8OmJjDbY20TihBOxxfgEVO2/ButLiCu/AWvTbAHXscfNjZWLoP2HFzc@OgtvxYlCG96yIYtjJlqYx1ELcbFNgKCmwFAc0WTqJrwoHACxpIw4F6cXcTtRVtS0XtRtsIF9acVTkgGdAXtIY5vZIyMfqJ16iJRt5Vdq@Rb6HkHhJ2PblXic45ox3uVxEA526cxMuy3I@afQXzuqD2x0Ru7/jslNbbmHbibFUKwj3qJZfWJcfF95XcboLvoOYePF@ZUID9Wybk@8qEIuEvJ/SyWDHuDvq3@ftltbNSE2sNv0FmVfyDnQYKm8Y/BdHbqCOkWCdOlxu6PEm7y9OZabRrz6ejwJ9ZHVG3870ofevgOuzElDRTtIYHPo016HJoaAVvfXBy35dm7e879lRNF43tDeOytaVOdeKRBYLWU6FV8@JRebL9MTScn7cOp9ltV9Ytm22Fpq1vWCJqi1FoeT4@yqpsPj6C8alI7g0D8dUv4D4nJ4UfvwTXVnzX2rQtj10aHvlpur@Mk9i7VrS6LAxd5bEd6IREkjR06ARRgc4X3cfP4hiaxRLMovWhHLBIO6aLHM3T10ZaT1Q1PK0BY79AX9jgRoL48ZjQ4qV5Ly1sUWR3ol2Cl3fbUS9/dlT6MoAfdlrFD@wi2GGGl9Zf8hg5q@9J7vHN5Kxoq/RqP5/e2ja9tffplWTdMF/STDxxtAefPy/poGuDAQA3ZAS/TIbXPqDlFTk7pKy98ZNsVoSvJrErGgI0f0hpEkCTNrhfAvnwrt8MeFsT3nyL/@8X4Cp69muLjxiztQXomxH5ghLpohnkeCpVEF0AXnCj7nmd3Fq0M1@Zlt3RIT08L@0gikvF7XJQMcdjUcVPFFnXCvEXZB4XDr2Se7KaKGEF7qFJn3rpYeDtIso8dkWFX4hdlw3p3cK7ynFV5LtEX31dxlHREaWnWd/hc7FebscUI9uaCdDxGyLDe6du99tiZYHIa@khk3GEwsLb/CMDdy9VMw6CJqw5EE0HDXpATj4i502NF@OFdRSCYn3/19ajVvtjlWQJT4j4IkOAD9a3uDjvJln3e@qz6lpn6StahDWsfzfLuNt5hRH3G78uw5/Hoi/nlIwyrCMlVqW8Y528VeLyeyW@JRUrmbSskq8TyS8J3VfL3JaoWcg2Kiz985qQV5jTvKIIgmsbo@Xzbolp6iudgH5YYpr6RqvyuEehrmMSTWfiJ0sSln3hpmRwFuA5hWcTnogQ@qCPlkCt8oZ27WrIi4SM@PGW1WL73Aloi25x0b09j7gFRa3cOJD7vE5TeDNN4VWawk6a6xqwm@QWECXsJGmXAhbPe0WgiJL5hnbGIOy5w@M9tQ2XqvE6zr1@dsrOY9lLO6fOY1DITtF5nHWBUnZ2nccZ4jCcxzXiGDqPL8GxqVvOH5zHq2qBADq8Escn9LdVOL4LzuO0y/1Mka@@r9L1O4/XZQowH61XwpFna3i1Y8/6a@tRVRE/sohGpZdGiTHgoWG27h685MfCPwG1jxOEwA8JOnBEgLEDstNobLUYVjrQbPjJV6Vd@5qP49XQlD2@sRlDgXBPYmtQBaVkQvSR88C5q4wswjCUDD7CEwhEvXm8nyKae9Uz@xI5duoyft4SmL2bPuGen9gDXRcJvwPg7UEcZRN/VV67KKwC/Do6MfJbdL4iZ5UcoQgXA7j3kIVM/d75TqawrF8cTWeV/nYJvR4jwEL0rUCsUiJot3Q62HBom5LExtp4V0hIKM72ydtx8LIrJUrvi2hEK9g1841g4m3nDBXDduV3v5edrXhI2o4KwsA79sGqZet2gehiDNroui1L1ap8QMKWzumSs2JEFNuM7SRwlrrxkrbirWZoFddKkmiuXTUJkf24FXXCm1bqm3kZ3KD687qvq5hgggONiGAr5joVS79qP8N@1yz7fWVQr5jwIoF9hvX@pvS1ef1uK/uCcmWT7OsCxEAvnXHvNY7WKWxYDr2DLcv8PVl7ZeLjl@wsI99KdI39hbW/Ytu6T/AFvr3sW1i40ErQp7ueQxyYHQbeZtRri0SZ@ldGix9TsvFYGV9Tusna@7RaGd9XxBiCbTQ8fnYB67sFvF14iI9kQH/BcquW42fKyTzFum6TD1tvZi6sWQcNV4mtD1rc8gR1T9avrZdogUf5sZopl4ptaHSj0aj79VQE1lqIu2nHqXenCdbdloAXz8qyvkut4Uoa3fxwrzpeLykjHmAM8GTexhI/u467bV22pc9f1F2IZ8FucdTGNdxUA35HK6Gpw2OTLdt8tb6i4DribSQr8xb47SW9NZw1QunACZ3HR9J8PT7i4pzHR7sVw6JZTyP97sD@kGJgs16DOthdzUQsLuPVgTQ4ADAZWR@Stgfg7KNmrHUoB/jNa3MVex1ropryarEDjg/Z36225vJdQQ5HJwrS2ofQgYsyXIEQdmEDYdzZb8VCaBz4JEsr7XQ@WIYOnrhsjDWVnJlJziEjZjue/2yshl4J2RN1xpNlIFYq5ECCLYqsBVmreTHra9kqOUsY4uLWMTKEvOKNlxZ7fjLjE4hDl2Moj62jFNdLPww3iUQIJmu0gMcdRRwBSTWQ3T2jyVcylEo/J/d6IEiM/WkQa4FLnYeoPk3ypVdHBB3QTV6Ru6vDau01YeSgaHscGNjp2jnjyaADEbCm4l7g7OYHjMVlMjSe48SSRVoECn5ReEQtZ8y7FfeDa@HefXKry434PrgesWStPaOyjp8BmfLqFp/traRbQ9P2pCXRA1szl6vjyij7eLkEmaf04xq1sctx4Fgd4oZOa9kErwir049ceO7WMfWNShQPrgCjBWttDRi4KhptZHrNvV6SqtK/oIMB8mljSI9YqSRZwGHN7O1ghzCIisRaq/tsBeP4RdfxC5xMpL45QF1oyRrGX4kyusmxtRtZpj/Y6KwJFazKVhVYvYS3XoLQ1fhmT8IfXA4PYPE43I4dTABvz358Y2ne11FBKbp/x9S7kVZOSyaT9RGnV8@TvWQ/WW3De4otelqDUJZhsnmlm8wUOotzLVqfSgG23r5OdYKeSrQ7H8v5UTo/zlJyqD3y3Abn8XxoGU4H00mBvZHOi1Iomr6RbgwxqYhxZjoYXnfF6rjD6YZ8WboqVZdMrnHd7F0PpNtWaxBVa9S4epvqXc/F61hLnTYb8YJxLTbTJXNYGpgTblGOtiKNmWqkmvVU/2JRmA3nhYjWlsPpazHalMb5mbAIj4V8g7qd1vuRWn4xjHOj7iKZNrrtqMfDtNOpXiwvdG@li1r6stvTw53wsBbng9PRhTRe9C/z6lNxkK5NBc94kCtEppRaKUxnYqg17Ch59bbabHYyqcpsyBm34@4g1LqamJ2YHgkGJ0mxPwiFCxNTjxVTycuomUkWmjnlpmneLpqxCmXmzXq0cSHEFc@0bArBSabBGGxzfiFf1maRfKCu5dULpTCoDM8n5xVlPBlmQnK5PgrpvZtcRwsE8te1ab5dpPTQRasdqw4CsYwwF5jLsKaNgvV4qahfzSepp7LYSgu1lNiJsKnwTZYbXJUXQnlarFZblXGrMYoal5xym2MHVPlGqCVTw1xxFOPqpUUhdl6oTdLpwnzaCUg9LTnptoJXN5FZsSQWWtdMMM9PzCuPnC4rzODiwlg0G5eFm5JxC9X66kIOSYt5qpnSpadM2riqFpmSPuzXQgO1O25G5bQmXFQKIbMwTOZnrdt4ITUUpUpnqA3rLaU1MeXMgMlRi/TwutERZzl5OeOzoWLzmhlkq4IZTfaCNWYgSZ2hUjaWvfPislebdHrdePmczYhPl91UM1zNjrmrnBEqqQuqXU9J8rJ6LXHDSjxfuO1kk/KVGk5XxHHlPD@dBwJtWarMwktufjPIheS5EGKL5dTNlef6IlD1FD2pVEULlntUIJM7b/XClx4tJy6ZosQ/RdMefTIJzTOTiayLxYaq6KOwwsZydU8/auit@NXVrGMUbqrplqAsY7dXw2HktkrdTAuGpgdiF7lknKkMWf2cH5QKt1FZzYVmqXMlGy@0lo2YmS1OlFi@2MtcVPVMfSTcxLO92mIx7MUuxEpxmKTEWKZaHXR6zc68XTMqC/YqJAw6nux5tvTUg3rcrOUCF41UpDepBpuXGXVaqec8S@2mVRynS0MuW4lNIvVocERN5xexZM1U5XHm/CoeuZ7IxWwy02ukOU0Ub56ES27I1@oLNmZE9evczfXY8Jj1jhbq9FPBxfVVm2neGkY4L1O381akkBzqwmV3bl4Y0boa0MrXLHctlRpKeNqSn9oVbZAcMZeNmyXTmS1z84opmLWhFu5Gw8PzufGkLy/1SyrWHvBKo5TWigMhctmWl1EmzKn1dlq6EtoXATbZ6OWvxFx@2ls2xFFgkH@a5AVeMCrJdudciUznY48UjE2LVL3UuulFn57Yjlhqx@XksFGtFMxAnWcm7Vox/FRsG0ZOaBTkVEhWJ5lU@3w4St8u@LoxX07qkY4iLSp6gM1S81L7qikMtJ6RM26FwfImd6teTQKRm/JAiprdITeSuWJTYqOlcdWT8VSU805vEWlOxKkAluH4ujDmUsnBoEyVuVF0mlrEDVM9Ny5LnfRFUk4mi7HA9TgQzQ/T5/l5V242mqV8l9dCt510MFLu9NhAN1XK9iqhUS9aKUVDxTRV7yyuq1w3E5O5Pq@kBxeL0DheDKQiTHNWzV8P6n21pKSTrbmUCgp1bRZt8ZLaEJeRKHPFegb9@IWaZEOVCNUwM2ajmJsFPepl4SpQWSyEmw4/CfLSU9vwCO1lf1luirym9ItPVa7enBTT8mDQjKSEOltO1djJ0pjx42KFimcqKpcpzqe5Wb/WYo1xJj@OdealbrpSETvjbnAsdcrJucROW63b6@tGWR3dXI/y1WinvOzyg3DTlKqR8tyknsDkaU6LjVxnnpEMaVCdPqnn88lNkwk1zkfFRnfqGcRv29OgfFNmi6VUU@Inhete1GyU5uOrC0VSmFGg3GOoWaOyXJpiUsuWZlftudRcLpNyynji5pcMXzwvZG5MTzybS2bK9RqvK@XyeTGT5Eezq1nxJuoRl7WrblgePt1SFVVVAvptTYmm2KARaIQzy7QwOGcn56lR/aIe58ZcI9@8urrk@oowEqLtcibSuhJayeTF5eJC4puVyrhy2ahTZY96c3tbZ8p1pRiXioVqXQsXpvpVqxXlZ1rymmcLoVFnVpynZleTSWsUv/C0TZEPaktR5KozpciIeZCdGCVOppV0qWIsAk/LwVNvmtFumvHk@DySTC@k7lScLtlkZuphjNx81o3I41ig3p6fS23hqte7rKb6wfF0XI@kw9RFXLpSm510/yq@EC/zxWZuYoq1bickewx2PKhfJxtGQ1jI50KkP20YbQUqnzQO11PpuKHcZmKXuuxhY0KKElpXfIUp9sM3pYuuNkvPr5qLDHQ5YpxUYcPaQm1OYkM1f2mkLltPl7FYr9HJDyHhSf@2L8gNT6rbEa8lpUTd3lw2h9nKpMkMrm@uopVG3hNbBvXzJ0Hrn/PxRX1ZZllRivemhck8OC4KsfPYZVlQLualakMSe5Fa4Fo5V5dURo322aTEzaYzlfEswqlYtielGiVVzzSEfFTUKjzDzFu3Zrl1E7sMnLPXbG00YwPG1YxhpbYqL9qldjvQpVJT43LcqnHTrCdvJtu1QVU4V5hSq1pYaotiNmA0kqW0dDmZLcbFhawHb4XieVqpCDIHZkk40qvrjeEyNe1QLWleTKdi0dtAHiTIMJT4rB3iRcEY9@YDpng1ySvzwWTY1D2jOVP13Lbn4Xi/2TcYoVislwqzrB7WLoyBSkUiQiDf0sdRo/o0WhTSZqbfbCihdLzZ65TzbeaqLl3Gr9O126gYrjCFJzHeqkVYoRhuCQxX1UZTE1okoTekigu2qwuKqPPRSfkpnJ1MPN3FdGJ6xrfR88tYqzdMc1OB9wSTHe2JnzcvFFYuRcWeUW7Npje5FliIanPaUKncbWMcvJTzUi3fLF8NuUqyujSZVLwl3IR6bZ2TVGlaDZrhi4LYiwpSJns7HGTyhacC25ae2Bmn6NfXwVyeo6KSJ2VqXYVpXo@v1WWAF5Ptcuxq1l2mR/2SJOYLgYzerka6tUteyUIzKj8V2XEzd1687XaUPiNparlWZVnqNhLItm6qT9y0e11Z1rV5Xu9dJCtK8EYqqFrlpsllrnWmFE3lrtOD6m16EYtUdKUj1nuxujrynAc1gU@qxQgVFadiqtliGqIc5KLzZYcfigx32xoOY3lmGTGWTFI1ZoNYbxnvnI@41m1JO68vhsz5aH5bSd1wE9HDcRVhTF2by0r4/LzluVycNwo9pVGQBIYfLQZGPjURL2ad60jSExuzdU@22@zPi5XeuJVlop1OjKsFg62Q@dStLIzrEtXMFPPBaGZhzqXscFKax/LjZKS2mDeuQ6Hh7WBejtUi1fCcm2rDbGqc64UZ7caIqvN6vpdLiVnpSjKulh1hREWWk1IhF8t6wiLfrrRvWSnLPNW6itnvSfXLm2AtwgjhfLkyu73NJJlRVBpkC8o5tIkz/mq@qA3aw8512QjKlFZuewqRZWRZu70uddVK6@Kq35n1otGKnm8O4pNle1yVq57xslHoaOeZykjJLG9A4CLVeHjQULKNlnyTqbJlyoy0kjOwwblUUV70mEKYvZRU9mI@Oo/fjFqRYXvYTE@r7flwEKlFw9pEXEbN1lN4Ijai7YtRjRE67VnfEzintNpycZO9DunF0mxcNCuaeMnGAsXbYWOUnTQ8o/RlrmOmW@y4E2gVZxNPOgxWQeyqGQ@UOpeDVGF4fm3krwNxqp6TF5PY4Dxy7qlAYzIZGOVYUwkoU6bFKM3ZVByOWL6U4Zv6vNPIFbulbiDGjD1ydGZeRp4u2pVb3hyHVIYyFpHujPfks2BBZOR2uOZpmmN2BH0R9mYavFR7wYCh3tRqgpnWosNGMC6GcnpT1ZpzbdAMyNfn0eFMkC8HVEpcdkNKo9rqlubLWTc@DHX52rSRzN2orWBaHffnhs5F4peBJv9UGenBsjmuFBtCSr0e8bw088yVVOZKr02pbq@U7LZyTxNp2gyVk6Hk4qbLhia30wGnLm@y7cCg0kn2pVm1FVpWZ8FU95xTqyN5PNIDDFtvqtlhbN7Ii5fUxTIrLvqx61SlGWpcDuLDoNIb1irsYliWJeH21phwhXaveM11C@Fm6jo@zEtGUow24tLFgJmXOuXbSLorhljK0y@MmEC6KAQvsjce80JQwk/ykiuZy7ikLkoNuVPrTZPjYnfQmJRSeSbFBabn8/IomK8ywQmfGsUyl3pbVygxG07OG@WriNG/TZrNkFYJTGPj24rcuwl0K31eGLGRGOjgq27ndtFIVlOzYruUrxlJtbcUPfrsUj0v5HIplcpLrdKT8cRr0iQZapSL7eun66Teq4c7plHg5k8is1io5Yu0ICzayYIxLDUvamohyo66qavodb9bVBtaRQ5eUkI8OryJMmpNuJiwYqiSDOWemufCU2EaqWpD1RTq2VvOLFVB2RXCjfK4PRst031WmgdD2Ruj3OuOb6G2DpZUYJKvtrtVaaDOZ9ULs3kZHNW4YXOmDCMqP/aEsvFymed6QeyEhW80daQplz3zplaaXuoM019GJuL4XLyUqWJg3EsWqpGLAH9@3s7EG9zoqSgGYlehSXIWKFevPGpYHGcKvZHCpofVgXgtQ5ehFakMLthaSW70bifpm/iiRi3bHSmuXrRm2mV6OMsMp4N6Yx6E7lW9WTSMWvXG7Bamgc5FVOmU@916Jpe@FtI8b0TLajpbHo4nzc5olg@FqUEueDO4il7IvcgwWhAX7cvJOF65WBbS/XzI01YvYmabN5WnsjJ4KnVMs/MUlZu16wumlYoKKvu0iJo3/RZjUPnYKHseEqPLQp@LNtTRdDLplquqVlhUrq@AzdFAsH7eYZLj1nXFbHbzonCTb4Clf6GJhdrNxbh2fpPvTroqpQRBfNOMfnleNHI3meEtNytUFx2Z8wzLl7NyOBqW4h3PNDwq9SeZcLgVHV2UprnMWI/Mr0Dr9yqLSlGslq4obnTVzg49FxLHxfSrZXMaqibFm0jnaibNQuFMcq72Y7EGO7@@OBeuY51xYTZqXHC9a2Z2Gx8aI77BV5OCJpWp1NM4uMjMzSwbzl5G8jfX4iAy62YngUJyVmsVIma8JLVaoadZdTYUSzlOqs@ns0AlV7421VB43ry@HV5CKYQpoTe/zkbFq5DYZeXlbVrPaR21wSdZ5oIJzBrNa4/WU59KomdYCeSC40iWnVd46BnfpiYX3UinMVBa56l8vE91Q0LWUzcihdvI083TlazfDDzREaicmFSdXl@BSdIxG/XQ/FqKt7llMx1r8Z3cksteMslQPj@JFwKBi2K82KaMWngE0vI0C9xcZJTAdaVZD008mVJm3u3XbhvV9OwqdtvmRpVWbXqBnbEgw86k8qDaWJRy84YsRrLDalZKUZ7C9cwox8dSNdPM6kylK@VCg2H@PHcuTi6FyTyretheobGYPk1GYuziSuFFXc1VzX5SCLZjw@BcKIyTT5dNapHnsxdcOtaM6UNZuBiUGsbAmLbGkpwMPYXnHrM6qMiX4Uy1fqMOGv1SSRfSV4GoIWaGtVHktjGYd6ZitntBSWZ8Kijz81LEVFOLnHzTuLq@6NbYhVCJXZRy@pztMLmnGjs1mUasVqn3OiVdLg6g4fS0G5oWU0ClmH3tmuLH/QI7ayYvu7GekT5nY8WLebkhlzzsdbY6yASMqe5h@qNyILPUshdBaRbtVa8vR6yennb7nstKlLkdpLRZiQqb3WCLN4bxqsS1201mnK0uDeMq1uh4Lq8VRqwGbqOp/JKrd4Lj7qTfjrVH59OndvvqqdOs5aE4bzxipHb1RPWuL/NGVIoLXLeRSheT2nTMXuijqhQaFbV2I9CWPO15pjB7ClyyuUGhw5VK/eUyJVzoLTWWGXWu0vxi0Ig1qWC2zHZvg@L4opF5auf6k4GQLs6F4I2WNzw3odJ8cq7HohEuFJ/yRrA5GjU9saQie6LB/qIfSGWnkQzT1astKlv2pFuaBrWgehvhS4wR6pYU02hE67VsvJrOpfPFy@yNVIzXCvzNjad9XUhnk/XIxWV/GLpsc0aKSV31B7UANSimh13GNGMTuSbnjOy5npn3b4fXo0lnFp0WjfZSveQncm/ESfx42Cqq0UjyuvkULrPB7BWTvV0qaiAansepriB1LxilOrxpxeRsnmkrfehAZ0D@hzdXE12QdKMfb0HOr5ZqNN0o95p6XulXgEKlMxkL0iguD/ti8JaqMrVYLtpSLiWh3K6Oou2OfFO/CEalyRz6r@3M8lLKMFDqjXatP2FvIlkwXUOhp0KrP7qelppGNZxp1ouVENV8qmYkrpAtFpu3Zpcrldlebmo2orF8lhNGqWEpu0h1UoVZTmi08p6BJ1DvCtNcM6lkm13emC9u2TirJ6UBFRlErlJShjNn4aakh9IX/XKQVwravHwRG4@qlYtA6iJ7LWlDnU1dJ1dXpLmIj@Twoiclk@fNQjvdo5LX6cwg0JQMoap6ZgUClsop/O9@9lEhoq6rBIyaanIXv2hliPYxFyfvHDxBTp7A7e07507gYp/tgwQke3@19aFer6OBO4SPrUTI3KYfv3aCU4snL@cWfdzqOAHywHM86CPyhRNpZyLUoWPkNRkfZPU9AsiMJ5lBwXkwsj35F8Yx/IAG7wolsInsqHMR3ri/SBvhCJ7zgeeMsg8nW1OeLm6bGiQQioxXJeCn1/ELPFXhW4hIpoCz5Zx737Q@e7ITH4gzxio5acTh8ztIVPtUDMT0/xZ3rVttJEn6N/UUibCNZEo3bPcFAd0ChK1ZboOE3T6YxoVUQLUllVolAWqbH7s/9gX2Afbh5kF644vIzKrSBeiZPWemz5hSXiIjIyMjIyMzI9IgZDSRbn0zOOyQxRysPRC/zSuWfyh99yP791A9d@h2T388c1@2NjLKHwZerxuNBrftL1fh9c2l6qj@bxd3rfEfvyv15rWCR6PVF@KDtPzdRpEdQH/P7jR/ZJ/Rz4wLUPbGD09f7LYRHkeXlbJuriqLKscfLv5Zy1SmuFS97BouFCcf3dPvzjZ6G6VK97R3VumtrOSGKxvDlfJKFgkvyrlKf6RvIp4Oz/jVfvGl2jdP6xHdBHd/w0t1FPZa1@FypO5qfiv15oQ9mpkJ1PX6yfl047eG4SCZcgl@8rqpiTidhFNib6JmEJpyw3Hfx9Gd9UrQCYl/8c/C6LvXlel89HBhAS40KvruRLIDX53@6KITtNacBaYnjsDxnH5tTTuFaSnw7cICpwWSKLioIMoiu2JyW2F/rCsHUuTc9GU9AXIzi7PVnPuUkqbUBfHkOWLRDaiYFBHypoorAs1HoznBCt97fs@eg8KPT64CLydq0eQZjz8oD75hvzvnQxWwlx76s650UfaBoXLa4wSnngZ49MZXCTaXJWvht1G3z@fPBcFXUwSBds/7XjCwNQvR6AKve1UZxAgM0hgBfNzDI9yNN/STQ2PGAhff@PEV@gN4RxwtiRBueYiaTrIRjw8Arx1ynQWJ5JxVw1AuVgoaui53I6eHmggH9@zL/eU1xffgKpTER6KVRO5vlIu@zsnuUnbXG17Pyb4G7FE0L3tA2YjvPCc7oGx5Ezk7P6R8OemfU2CIW57ErufD8HzoBZ2sOPSAK5B7EdhZtbJiCGtZQMnAyHik6yvtGkUtyugIs6XYi@Yns5UUAEtn9eTB75hbOBfe67PCF4k2hSbqq3q0MX05kkh8zi2R2EX7uZcp@CqBAM0/EqVqOt80LqNtO5rinwItO1cYbSLWK/Xt20OYaUZM81/5zHCfjBDu4SZ6KNSK4Uj42XhcpdIfutLsOtp1TFK6mTsScT/MpFyNRYjMrXheXwa9NrVBgBeTybjylFM/xSmn0Zlas9IjpqNMi8fpuDrFPbgRxTPSVRfxZ@vpVPXA91TToxX5IhYW8BPmVabIGdnS@XTpTSptqTnBZ60Uz@hZ@lc7@7TeLBF@PKmZNhURtC1SDTc1gjPQ82RckzJBgD1bXpN0BMsN0sCCOcDEn945ARiuEw5Y2YwYN2ti0CvIm1SS86XV1y5fMZci9zGZjLB6Cp3@HyYXCKeX7BHiB6ZFkppBmqnitt@g1@bklJvonkj62Z07lUfNyz8tA0c1zU/MdT/RKrmmSso6bqqo@8fl0D9Hma/x8KX0nSg7X1aYQTec@BQWvJ9D6EeZLN2F1TOVojhQYMnwyJLETghnL0rx1fpzk2KuXcrcnquBAatKOh84C0CTQYpysparda7NWHRq74vnQ6PcuLEWhrC9whWkslecpDjHdm6XF@9kqnUdxRRJ5uAlOzTMgcEsuDS6LanBpl6hdY5hFiKDnjSnr8KwnTUKk1YYGILx0EGFXHFnZdUqUS/j5qk5rfSqK@3lw6y7FUpZ1Em8rlAClE/Nm0Di5RVPmwqmTUK/CSKOKs35WI2oKfP6AJcVRfqotcl0lLYq0MLMSkbiwycZe67Ucp5X4pR4yGx7PVwMxXDI1no9g3Q7ECizSRvt2L8lj8H9DCuD@PDU3i2/JrcuQSUoQCe2g25uQeYqFpv19QyasQx//@fSYnEUDYoXQa/o925Iqb4YO0vK70l4wzU1Gl7mf8BF4erx2/damvC9bL6ESGxCI4XWCj3/NosypDnDi2gm54hPOr60WHbgl5jvjXf8mzZp/eKxpR9Gd/zvmDYLpcKoPww5RzfEvuvUt@Bb7E@1xK@I9I5Bo7POcOIyWbwvkNSx3JXMl0VBKsPnci4B4hQ1WeBmPmUyGD8gqu@Tnp45UcH3WtdAArz3TbZTNFzMyfdOZIYevtZACjxeoc@OeJno891RNMHaSTTm39R9/C7jQ1L4iiv4Xu9THL4QjJxOGPbB5LgKivrrRAAh/EKjuVM7Pi7owEtyYx233OUeM54IssM6jtdgr/HitjrcBcqgLKCzgC3tbcTAWf4yjdCsJhOmwi3IKbSCP0LpQb7Mv6a6YcvnpDiThJ876V8RaFnSXj36pEeBdnG1bKJa3lQzhROkWHiUGl6rBUcQ@343JIy3/U6HkBZaLMTkwCcoYtpfse1Hp2jzzCIv@fmp/HwqvyD5glRcqtC6HsSF1pKFMktf43L3KhMXc6fa2lDU6foBe5cqhIME3pWHykYF2qQFceFNO5TClTZjPZWRT@T8OmP0JWcxVccyuM0/lXzN36t65C2WqbI/p9vHX0cPkM8@GPSTxQkuLfSCzk9ifrQ5LGEV3CpJdYw3s51MSm0Q0eIkT2KCmJin7eZGDGWlbCQOz5nM5vrPmYI2Sf2UnUQjxy8EpibWjDmSoBK3ucKEu@OVhNrh7MUECIYJRlNm5m6aymNdeZwAi1KLplnHeApNT3Dq2uQU38C17m/4x0z2NHKm3NLszAXB/E46Ly8t0gRiobuYmU2mtDQZDka@JOpOPbCKxG2PJyHOFhIHIXagrWtICtumL@9BLsNRr71o5URSUBhJMUV3m6MpHRcoG/adN4TIvHf@LL503npd0go7/p2qQqf22FO/k3psM/SjYURzwKcODlQ06vc7gfbrpm75OYf0s7z6Bo8RYogJpaHg1PFAVMq7@NKPY6hSQR0C8i3eGcYZ0egKQeVhCUZ8dBKtlwGBHBacam/MnonZDdqqPHnx1Qh@XCGAO7TtSyAhIyezhy0P0NIKjnlYJF29lPndG5IKRB0P2echXK2uOc7fR0Hry/ZbtVoqfV8uvSonSGZM1aXCq9eqnlCRTMZqqVwqvSm/dpztsD@Wp43ZVg6wXucB0FV7WOjfE2/6N4hf7lRpxeCCEan@kT@48dsFxzn222wDvhgxRcDKI5CrZ/y8IoV0K/i7J3W3G7mKtl3XEC/4i/VZfNe22LGG6@ANUd8fdIOhvDQKb4I2CGjeTV2GnU54y4ZoPFkSeqBS1x8SUV7mVBol9kurcWHdhd3FEjUQ84Ed@F2EN@xHWpOB9NQA7vf5AZADJ4qAkGys157AhNprdbygC3aagQC8LMUUMAhQ19qjlv8gDg4j8RdxULpj7bA1gmdez4xMkaRfyHOFprs/CEj6xgTmUeFqCdxpgJvv6g3VONxtfqge1xR9Hx0fvq/v1HbU1kfVfFdT24dHHznImHp3uEfSpaGqBzuUetA8rm@dNA8pIVNtUM0MZzjVg4@q9svRca3RUIfHqr5/tFcnaAT@uHrQrNcarqofbO@d0GL91lUEQR0cNtVefb/epGLNQ5dbNdWcuJ463FX7tePtd/SzulXfqzc/cou79eYBGtul1qrqqHrcrG@f7FWP1dHJ8dFho6bQMWen3tjeq9b3azsFap/aVLX3tYOmaryr7u1NdPTww0HtGMinerlVIyyrW3s1bon7uVM/rm030aH4a5uIRwjuuapxVNuu46P2S426Uz3@6GqgjdrfT6gQZaqd6n71LXXOyT5CFRqX7ZPj2j6QJko0TrYazXrzpFlTbw8Pd5jWjdrx@/p2rVFRzt5hgwl20qi5CsFiuWmCQdSifPreOmnUmW71gyatGSdHzfrhQY4G@QMRhrCsUtUdJvDhgfSWiHR4/BFQQQceAFd9eFej9GPQlKlVBRUaRLXtZrIYNUhEbCa7qQ5qb/fqb2sH2zVkHwLMh3qjlqMBqzdQgGCi3Q9VavSEe41xIrzkk5jVMZzr8nCq@q6q7ryvA3NdmjigUdfcwmTbfqdpTnO56Mw8cnvwAG/6lE@bQh52Er99uFMjjU8CwWTi9BNadH5IH96l8mihsZn0U5@C8lp13vYvRlfnQe8yxNbcVpMT7G505SLOUg4Bfj85DwRI1wflXGFp6fz8ffWc9rmN8/Oc@5SaKTQeq6G9sD5UKqf72Am9Nm/zU7alJKE2X2hf7644Xk7aWl5Y40NOFYttX1fD40UANmYiHZSAgLUhGflVo9dTiSb5iDltK@KIGZPGInO8GUb0T@9b/EPWhkQCCWe5t1AsYg/LaCDyibL4UyMcFERHBuF7AMElN1mIfP/LVbaUbA5bfm2gypk6XHZI28CrbO6R6hf@1UT1/GR9RhZvTVlZMe7gjZt2MGbIvzTJlB6XwoB7lhXTHv/JGWy4IVIKc9IUP2TVt0@yL6Q6/IuKrTBXsa7EORzIfvWX@gds5kqrrysT6e9suswtvDpHbBta70653hn/eXcmBWiCBdh@EUmCsRypFouJOqSVsT5pC8NX/TUK3QZtWlOxVF/7vKzDQ764C07Wp8V4ENwlsScx/Pa4ur91srtLkhPYvv7hzfffVRztcX8w/MWVvx/RDiJxMnVJi74NSE3jrMQs2Sa9Z3cqWE4iug9GDwURgtIMGid6pNJaz5miI0h8DTEDobsRIgz0EGQjgyABg4zC@3x/0TH8OnNmagbIprqaQ2@63h1r@B6pSswDLfGS2RnzqN3hH8C2099McdshzUCaxfxufzgmzqXNBcu9zK5xOMB7G35WjCKFjOHjvmfuIAlhIDPZCwPe4PMvzduJUSS9FgON@crDzjUJicVJLEyQFg65RE0chZGZwZIYUMovmt/o86MODoQshHqoDhtExl1bM2@C94jNWU8MDflsc4OG6MUL29K6giE1p5ES@386dExyNjAqcqFBTQA2N48snW0OG6F/Xs6pr8Kp8OoNOBXNsfo3ce6s7mgoFeMSXf82EWSUwIoDynDSrW3DMUU@miKWnCky/Uv0YPj/RprMgL9OG06CHlOL5XDQG/lPpCRDFVrR7pWJEtyaG2OJa2oxNZNJH2Mw98mBubYd09fw7uRgiUigR2dsEj5KSLHsDAKAyWHXSM5fOPDlSXzt0c7pZ567C3LSP@i1uv2sCchlloopuGcu61yuuSKHHzk5wi@pRHN7iK/yM/t5ZJmBDRdJsYuxeh5lBMZKmWUOOl18yUYPO8uZNUGGspnhMTuV9NQyk/9O3zCKV5m2yb0nVXR@sC97HIKYQimBb05AjADhu0/JDmuyUZubQHRmv@Hpha38Sq/iiH5JIpDXZdVk9xyRd8l7ZixF2pcGnHagScB53tYxmy784S2Wi45AZx8iMTSVfc5uTNCItkVaNcII31yBqM6L7K3Fns2U4FeL/UnvSw/Rl30xcZkShVQEqKQL1oLa9zgYVOdp/c7Eja@ArJvp9us99qvSkvNKmOZ4506tYKf/PIopQhrnLbRLWodiKnmtL0jMGB4NbvPBHf3htvK65yamEe0ZOGLdLKX/fu6GALwycQdWZT71rBFpTRayjedGfcGXzF379RFf2s68QZ0i5CgFF2a1GgSUoTfhkub0bGP8Um51cPl0jTSn29vChTfqer1Lrxt0xnzr9LfwuleMeqOoX@iPnUwmk7YGwhE4XKQQ7kNffQh67fA2Uls0HWBIahycNI7Shr@E5WtbLF9K/Y3aUFvcsjMF/hI@k6LwckhD41fUWEdEH8TmHrYTaksLm7XGSIBjqgEzELXbtZrx24MT9dbv@QPSB4/4zqXaC1p@j8QHKVN8CzO6FkmD4rtovaFbV7vQXdiyU1F@wEYda9tzdAMamgvWytJUJIQHOqwibPNjYvWETbAw3eG4X21jVLoO@9obEIymUDbFxHk56rgOYjd@qDffYTMuG3O2zdCyZmx9sCWK6tQVYy11ZuD1hmMiijNpvCG0H7PdFBQ7AyKIznxy8qaui@jtbZj9OhF1FeHstRTgFYSmqh/cIFgcm@GeMkZ8z1abzWK6VbR/RVfC1xnRkRo9Jx49FzFDC65686Nq@uBdddTxWrTDUo0Rqr96RXrgVhgNUXS/qlRptVwu58uvYKI9aVQLPBHwfxNBzHHq@0eHx00ipHaRbxjDrpkgPgftkttYRI48QndR7z9DIJvyJDFXPzPxoIIbP76ZipxYZNYyNPYtD@Ze6mGUVofZJAuTfDjgwGHwBkUslJqO1CqcHiBEHwtJtJSA7nLoMh18TJYWiyd78@MKn4Fbh/iqg/PQz1yZ00gA@HecRrUGvDNoa7f3NCZdv2uxD4ZmdfekgDMZ88wSTGypxBzL7jK0JKJeLgmn7eOORIToAd3opjUg2eLdEMvhCotxiUU8w7IpZ3vjXQSdgOYA4dW6DrHgiLgyA8EmiGRENIdH3MbawYLEuMyIVkCzqx12bVHBynGsMzid3o/GrVAtXdE2GzutqO/7bY6UMOpLKADkF2iWd2jlEDdxa3GMAGepxPcmByRsEJKFZN@oA9@x8PV3IWPumN4QVxn3gs1rbOsFEPWoMeRJioht2Rk7bFfhnDfHw@4RQ6BuDoSY4@iPQPRdHEoRVjTezBD8xeziwh1Vh8d70g8gKnIwoqifzgAsOdX10xkGPPquP6cKCJNuWAQmXAwaZMRPlnynbGDpH@gv7p3CaVpW@kidG@csMXcDhNAU20CorkL8i8IFQzE5I/T5jHDKceEdXPISvMmS5emSVMoGEEmUXJ0BMz8T5qvZMPMapj6srPdu2GEbajFbSC/EG3RI8hGEiLv/NjSil93KdUI5YLK9v@qEF4jbRJKCWsOfsRsPbDKZd2ApQidzxYlgOt7UuumSRl2/bTK6i1qn@eFvqnVjsdj81JOB0hkbMpfYZ5nitYunE3/iHz2j@DOTCl4FrWMiehXQk1SS3QCb0SB1SmZNxTMTN3GS5XXL6SrdVJXyRBWNXLrKRarKqhN7Kp0YXdSA6MffdM@MXsK3kngE1IYdoJLT9e5kd1NiB3RspkHIyJRHvNUzzSAoeNpS1qcdip85sYvm1LG9tGF@8hU8vvGdeZbhkFeldLyDO3N1j8UAl0rlj9kNeC@rO5TTZOAf1v1zziCj@7XOVXoJSWU7LBlOqtsDvNXKJlvJramlvienhigVYWFLNn3KNMApfYb@e6myuoF8ElkpBLe6WhQS4dn18iltZWVYjBwsOfHKzL8SAo5G0BH5zVfGZBnIZlPzykhuC1M@p2Q3gUK6gOOWHPH/GZFeJ6lYURKioQGFD2FMtZLn39H2jM@YGQSvP9ZirRPFp7GVHhr507jlM7NqpHsxt/TkUjKrTGJVsVR4qLAhtqXT3MLzVxsmHWwIkHdSPEG6PRiJNenMErwcCclYSwmG7Ow0bAUiodJkSwhdqevOEMDpITfIuRO9chKuzHUPJ5cRJ7Vyppgkm/iFMO3quQSyE0A5J1UL9J834LjumJzYc8uVpZwe9nkcYWGZcX@ILWxhM@4PsYUUTgz7w2xhYhla0nL9Sb5IjYSQAJcS9Y6BbUpJGWQy7pKl7iZKMULjs6Qvc7@TnYFtQqpqW6czpSpZEunQJek2@M@dDMySdjSaYkci3qkdjbO4t7TGtb74beuRWffebpE2M@klQUZzMhABOm1a4DE6yyFktq1AEluMYHrP3JW7m@zRflk2LLwHRdSuq@v0694UWLOqlHLTCqXx3h8jvz4T@fx0FIV4i7U2HR/e3i7TWOPCUzhoo3TGmXHi6zyC1UoCq3TvEiOUJvEcSPknQco/AVIxAUlP7Fe0XvLn0gBx6vzHQHz6NA2D//xKGykNgyRtO4ARG/vgW2/8GMxFUraW@E6dJ7fKbIVYT34Mxk@TMDgu6LU9jdOJ1x6sbn/4g3AyKsdcyqZ5ZQZGFqulabRcoMVSm/e7upxRlXhvW/hycR3YncDS4yMtfox1ZVwlvraHQEtpr/oWWDz/y3Po5yaGNT0fBPGUGYa0ZecvTocCCCEWJnkqZiskBFl6H6oz0oR4OHdS@PFuddL7MQKezq2We7QnP4vBJ2F0KlPXRGKlOM5s4WLhZFYrI99mbc8ebX9pZvv9sE86zuVMBLh8F3Z8MUpNiPRYNZ3YWj9pLZu5nk33K6m3TcQmefokfzHV9VXqOh6m06Tu@bd69X8Isu6LGYF/QpM/NTwyB8nnM5HEQbunjVuqN@pe@APnKVNdahTwR/ZI8znXcZaWVLVFW2btGR9WsRaH7/N1k1CDwQiRGvVxXhPJ5U5MbtjIfGHgybLt8LbHpQsZNME22q7v9bSrfL1gXg1wfmHLugjficdd3ELQaxGhIz9h/vwsManbvs7BjeQHyFqZPfbgarSpsXDjljRaomtmx@k9raTOUXCsVsOl1iYVFcM7OAx9KZq51pdIMc/NNoE9RXt6SCEiJp7XpN7wToB@mEfX5hNz1LektEPzBFLOUreslfsJ6tb4qerWv4GSkwPqJL619qAX2LVHhdrkJt/5s1i0gRm7M1y3vG/u7qYcnlyMza6g6w/elEolOMG58CI@tUh5w8EpcRAW06WLsIkX@7d/G7y/KKIqDi0QmWDNHGb6UdghURMVwsGVRKMADlQUpXE0AT7B0cSI1ptEuAfYc3p4lfNbJCXFA09b8TXOwF5uf99k5mOQIJ6/pj6jg@jfZ3U56okR/daTLYOGYu6bUW2ooTcZc02OyIOES3jUsVfSGBjvm/WrBRx8bGx@dRb4DFyeC3K4@NzX@Bli5p3f6YSu@hAOOu3FjLwOTVfY3U1WKEkRXCWUyRNx@GJX@TdBJxHCGUWAW9jxC53wisHhBFw/W@S3TAO/j5O0LNaxY/@qdtfPZk5/zRBjUpdX0M0VlTnD856rDC1RGT5CfxysBMwgtJ9Uuuv1sy2m02RhWgP1W6r4izB6VXZVQ24Hw56yTV3GZY5sqkhO/MIIzR4vDaLORrfwWxj0stR1ZDt4LsdPv3l4uSdzilviZj7dlS9Bw5LA0DghRM/TatxX4HTqn/8frNuwHOBxI9t47ZPYhL@xZD@MMR4zS90MLy9peoklftO4GjPgWFTmy3xLAaTRAzvwf0esguzyZbQsAVZw1aYx7rVSiJyunrlqeTS8/GGZIPxLfXTMDNTTj@iJaxP/kadpvTviON6xPGMzHC5QTMsdVDhHBcd53tr4/TZbrVbVs/7KiqpWt@gjn1fVraraQcLWltqh31v4/WJj9c2bityc28l9pcQtk3ivtggGL0ErtBHYoZ@Ut4EdFbZSGOJnxY1nbuXZ@cb6ZiUqnla3zorFK/r6x3/@9z/@63@KVf3jf/Fji3@c/moLFQqF4rPW12cv7iv4fbpztvzs4vRZ/2z5qgIu@z8)

For Haskell 98 I used [Hugs](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm) compiler – [WinHugs](http://web.archive.org/web/20160322122725if_/https://ndmitchell.googlecode.com/files/WinHugs-Sep2006.exe) on Windows, `sudo yum install hugs98` on Fedora 26.
Command line: `runhugs polyglot.lhs`.

Previous answers print 146 in Hugs (same as in Curry), so to add Haskell 98 it needs to be polyglotted with Curry.
Two dashes start line comment in Haskell only if they are not part of a legal lexeme ([link](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.3)).
In Curry it is not always true: `/--` does not start line comment, but `--/` does, so this can be used to separate the languages:

```
x --/ 2
  = 157

y = 146 --/ 2

main = print y
```

In polyglot (lines 99-101):

```
>x--/2
> =157;y=146--/2
>main=print y{-ss
```

Comment: So this defines an operator `--/` for Hugs and y is assigned the result of applying that operator. In curry y gets assigned the 146 directly.

Answer (score 6):

## 164. [CLIPS](http://www.clipsrules.net/), 8204 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment afTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVk-VkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 ~ B   =  =   =  = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
module x where open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"               ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeStr
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \\     @,,1'1'<>   @125iRE                               _
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001859

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkhj4uVL3D@5LMMEuZBJA4kGCD4BAFYqPLnZXFbkkq2p6QBQqkUgAWQQy0ZkACRSLbbu6s9E@ZHfS7GhtNHvantnT2a3Z6cOapDOTbNfszE5fZfsjej@und38gzl3j8gXHiRrRjIdSCAj4@Hh4eHh4RHhEdHSvd5vfpPADztx@tNu3xmxkemNWNu1rkxXY8@m7KluecXCuiRhrJrbHQ9Me@SVpATLM2bZhtWGdzZyLk3b@mi64F9gbOg6XVcfsFFPHzHTM/Sh6TFnPBqOR8zpLE62ztjBwPlgZTDlwLK7EG1kukPXHFH4BmOv7b4@aLX1mZDiTIZDF8I9tm/2Pw0@jZjhDAa63fYg5iZjLx3XMzG@YXqeg8m3GJscmMYM0G2IqruW86L26suZoB3GvgQU9WHfnDC95Y1c3RhZjo00ybGzV6/PTmZS5PPszfnh4axvgX2dcWx2ODYuY0FE6xPXaY8NpMOoZ0Iw0q5j9U1PMqCMVTYUNaahgyWYa@ptHk3qOC7DJGxw2WcWM4ZD1urrPc1gfQviHua2mYmkZh8hvN/z2GQ4YJ41ACieMzCjuHjMNs0284amYXUsgzBg5mRk2h6U2NOYBbhfW/0@a5t9SBCiZaQBGBt7ES@OhCa1HYnBxxjOFCJ4WzUhjm36hDCHUBNICAcrDqji0@Pa1YdDQBKIeQaIj6wB8Jk1SnrM1D0LORmSeKbdJhoOAx53mG5HS8muLJ3pgO/YJdie6WKFagSX9UzXBJB6wGXKtWuNgARI4ho7MXWXnbumqcb5PZYlZOZgDiMsiEZVuLubPDg@TEJV8hSaPhxJCXf9/Pe@knSmVdhqswzfiiyXpYNX@@xm9QLdnL2huoeuoqus8h3zshcXJnwn@Va2695KAFUCqvRZ1hmOsnpmCAhmRoBgVkcnujJXBW3Yj2TMdmfqIsJgPFYbaoMd2exNmkpmjF0Xm3BIVP0SCt137C7QEwrrjm2kh802c1AFhgMtMM3MK6AasDzVkXNNFD7vWVBpHlZJpDFxQUQEBVEEvCco6ufrOf0xxYOU3ggZEKgCSRHiUYe9YR3d6mMSCEdQHGvX9Mb9EaYZ222seRA0ZltjPhqG08ZIA@cKstMBKHlAexpEWiEhBZGhIhwqKgb98M/@vN3tApyaYThuW7DrG9Z2DBKZOiELcoghwzq23ie0IF4ac@fJIYMrvW@19RFmb09FFoQE5XrtjPtt5kCG7rUFTaunX0Fz7HRMY2RyJudSNs0G@iWXHRbnXCj4QG9BxVIGlDcVO8Oe7kEtGaaUIJ7JDMajzjbLDA9Y0su@U56UlCcrFyYgp2rq2mo22y0Dw2lr5AVvybs4500tJh29ke45VlsaTkc9xy6wjMFko@IMTVtJxmAk00m3lVQ1lGmKWrYqhtax7LaS3AVerELGSbVsVIy6VWqUZ5JHswQw1wgGm6upGKosgcihRnGVHeiWrQ2n7E1GuCJhjtdEkmOwFvFGwsz6XXGPBPUyyJcOMgjIIc3rm@ZQyWl5FcUExltYbgxYVNIZGKLAJauRSiaSqWjRCQKUNFZQbKznloNiqz/sYQcDRLG9IYhvF3nX0IF7PJTiI@jq06xFfE2iHyQLycRrM@marAWC1OcjapK8yWH6DApKASFsQn68eIs225EGDcIA2vTIm5PKfecaMibcsA8DEWJj5noXqggS8wLVeIF4juQTL9qlDYIFobVMtp1pWdAYsNmBbBe8HykjRF8v8DgAjTeWiAwa6FOAYvA@MWw4zOpAmxqAmHCnzDBR9oAQMnnHgpmMqR16oOSgupPLFIrFeFuba2ojN1vL/BiE9cfsnS0KCx9tVChwWMe8Zn3d7o71LupZNiTRDcMcjoTAgpJ4IxBJs/0OeWZEJ6p5PWn16Wze1JmI7jWSBwp7XnuiS9RRyghNK9MHocp0oSuytuWCeOpPZ3OHCFczmcvvMUoMgffyEhR8TQCYzJyYxngE0g0Y@bpnGT3gXcTO5vKRd0az2YNXNHeQ8JlOkDUik68@LkhaNvBCNJaCyGCNzsOBThZBVWMeVPlRj7sh695gAWAnQBE6hIivltU14L17YA4c21kAFAgZgMUo8RBeD6CRnaE2CB2Yr35RYw1UxKCKoM5AekDLB/7rjUZDrwT9hTXqjVsacEr23J0ejY5tZJbsyJ1aI4e7W32nBeLZg/aZ9XPIGuOWNZkpEPkFdfjBk65AEet4rAI9@Ldj4Dol2fFAcJL/HkaOBMkkwAkE/5UhIkXSgFBKxyORfAhC5WxqG4qsUVPSoNHJaSZjw5VVcGCqgC57zgClEHtLCgJqfM9ckFwdkFZC9pPo1xd2eUEfQPpdMql9cCxbuUmurKwkS8kqSPiVlSfg2kXXE3SlwPWEXBlyYTwNXZQiTS4MrVMK9Gskb@s@5InawGqbYO/00Roqer1UWm@k9XpePAv4VEHUgWSD2Bl8AJykWqmgU1Xl6jUUVGt14qXfQ@l8ZrjWUBDhK/1K5@@CCutEBmswdFxUZMvY2d5Nk0HFhd4QlFejp7jJi3ruonFxc9FOXdwm05haLeuVFhQK8lMGWtd1xtBtqvWNUibfUNX6OnSWrUoyl1xTlO1MHzLSVfWLbTWlc2orSROktnJxkQSiCvrUjZ5L8CbpgqoGpAI8sIMG3VBJajfbkH9LbaipJKRVk2kYalSSSaCMgUTwqNDImUSgQ2DAvbMXsaHe4BLEIzO8PuoUGZerFfCaXeOebXoEqlOJHVHPakN/CShAd9kOhji2Y2fsMSnCpKU60YxoMIYxyA87DxSMViwOAu5YE9D0oeFOfY0GO2BUavZguOf0Te0t6RgyA85n2F61hWrNCe8XNMMLKxEUGHAO@7oBLTMO7kJmFwAQGDWbXRyilucAz@o8NDy5r4zQMxi6jfRrW6R@jy2vh@QFFQnHBG4HqIq6N3TuJlHtiBnQaXeB0ubEGnFlHBjhDJM81z1FRfWvxtUn1Nqwy0ek/KE79ceOAQMXE7p@DOWjQHZgX1muYyORtQMADRxbxjqYAb6IvMBGtdpRYX85fRcBB4rNeecjtI1CnSWu4Rksazt9p@uwNYiArKlpnLGPbANQAKVtBONE5lkfiUC1rgMjmDgPmthfe6jk5TfXAzVax5hZiq99AGHBFhc6jLCkzGdHPz4AEZ8v5nKAv/@Wo09QyAiU2TKip8HCCKLZQtM/741NyTR6DpMvoIMsVFm2bV5lsbnJ0BP1QNPLgDZluqRLBMnEFJQ0csaglLTNvjWwRkc0R9O3secNexU/dA/YKwRwYpkjSajLYWeM0zWhoLS7PP7BBOWpJ5n0ZK@O9w@aJ7Xz5xU5O/bcbN9qQf21zeYA9Ka@6cmMJdipCalFgo@X/VPHGVWoSnBmaP6TwEh@/Bf7zRdHz05rp9/wbCidZw3GfR0z4/HP6N1nk8i0Usd1BoGO6Anarq4jNc3YNCAOnEToBoaOxSRgxH8T/Qc4sacZUtcwWMbhr4GniLiFEXGyTzOGQ6mbSmFMmvwLPEXMbQKJE4Ca2/I9d9AzmPqLqOFRcIvClycSkG/yuVsE7tljbxgp2U0@T/5Xo04H@5HAu0DelxkAAwokp@85CJsXDgiWF5ZH86xRgktBD3YhyX43HOtt5TCkEA6LWeZq8XhejgKiuofaunRQ@wtdTRi7FhFKAGJw2Z9P2QEZTD@xqHNIzYdwnhu0OvSzIEJJDBGhAeGEJVLlK5zuwlGqAz2ieU3RSNklYEAty9azp/RAtXcRPnEFPoZMy@yMobPIgjaC7nuiZXa2KWan1bKWRQW6IOr@c0E0d9xaRDZQvntzYzwWI/xo7I76Zls8//Pvt6EC5qunp0@pgwwcTaAb8UZnaW2JpPhCP4trluJ8GPctnchArvtAGjpOr@n9wLEYNMo6lsn0dHeA/ZCoXGBO/IG2dAefccxdsz9um/5zcSZE4vhIkqe2rQGVCJ6oSJFivCT5zDiYpydVpO/obYLCFQbLDGub14s54V1npJMFcfUAPP3hKgvniWFcNhrzX5wavq9erSF@F1OlFGeyXFFv5c2s4@kty7yDD1z9ctx2MsPLLhUaUdtcxu28EeHoKtPp65fc2UTnYgLwIrpWtwujSvFcFu26BwqBNwSVIntNjztYxRfYjHpV/S6Ybp//Lovir4oFjuV0svr08zkMSSxiQKtB0uKiTSZCJmuGsH29NcVxUe/zOQszpJ4QBE/FSKVy69gpBpN84fLQcLg8PXbhlH5nZ3FqvpJEAAyn0zHN@1oz9EjWQO9nCu2Ic6lw9kftoWtBVNJUM0Zf94BJRoLM5hVUC/3cxbjYyRjILqHrDrYN0fHncpdNB4Zphpbh9C1vyFuSeFkmJWcnUkIwuF5IP2FSfJunbxvUcezAM4FrcUN3jBFOyS3howcILj4bhvONEcbQnGW0M5xr/C5VHXrOlcl/F3dmHxdi9QARlOkTZ1jGguRt4z52xcUd@llMxcuFWI2M/kL/EnvpOG7PtD1W0HL@9AHOqOv9Pp@eOz86Xs7TntV3PNDk8fcuWoDG7nn8dzE3R8lm6XaGJkmi7sXJZpHSxNBySZ3q/a7T39zuZnX4WVrxY7eDAl48HyrYAsGUz98rmAL9x7Hz4rlUol/C/308QfMxLk68Rpx3dKeLpJiYsFteQBgl4GrK4sId5rYppZblo6tlFeAavWt96j9/i05jGXX9TmM4Je0Z1DtMsLMNjpHLNerfJreNu3NrP0w0zYHduq8Qkcq97JsgqOl3rkpZIZf/zBT5XO7hgqrTH5tjc6HgOG59MNE45Q6R8XCkcqIYq2KmIQvEw3mGINZHMTZ8ENbYjePbnXJG71vQyO9VYhaKvSGo3EMcTp@A4wQd8wm79ngYq9wI7U7H9undlOsN/ZbttGNIYsjnSqTt@1WlmFbumfRdpsEfDBwYATsDUB3sB9S/AEpTN/w3Bph8QsgfLJzmcu@EW2LBCg2oraCGQK1al14G58oeJngKy4buFHlnBwZntjma4u8yai8SpC3H6X9O7YA8bVuonYHOiaZY99XSnMojFutYOEnh4YRHq7NseoL3NWIcCdTDMfPSij6BIo2oc3hILc/Nzd3Ra0Vm6u4bTkKPTXNAnmv47mX4nmLjzmvb2tadCHOt1GmZfZ0/Jpsbd8Hb0dYfohkNfXWXJmtxgpdP6YYLDIkZETScArGsdsYzeubApNc7dH29/WHs@Y@lkSYOfhcEa1mazVySbmhBm7fxNzZ9HNGKRo5tetmR7nZNHKX0cVZf@C6Ts/4k6ULiHg30rnl4L3OFkxBoyUGrZhHn4umIEl9cNSDZPZKEDwAd@9Kcev5zsZo8NaA@x4M7oS1q5wbOdd7bsLXswrnhe9Q@u@f07J7Zc6lxBG/Lmgdw5Ihbpt5VCMC/p3uXaLpCMikc3fW8KHX7Tr//EOqiTOQS0nEWT8MeoM1oG5J@Ftyp3oIA8bh3xg66biIS9eHL2k7PHEMP5TkjZ2hm6G1Z1D7O7fDfxTPLR8dJj721TLfNl@1wok8fWa2@ya4tQOGDF13@Wjxv1Oo7OlpH3aHEA2X850NmogzHva9X6OrOaDikR3PYH3v0QxO6mc7imcoSOyREH8IL1ogvmHKONbtOy@hZ91Vey9RHtnWZFa1fvC7m8rgspoJbLLOP3lrfAlK5Uw15oBINP8PH0eJ2b70QduV36iN7Y9ed3i8b4ouBweQqXxJAx7JpGLHIsyCYen60CvBXv@9YlxBrQksZinRp1JszZg6Uk/zSSaGYBYMgQX99fXQPlQzHuLxXnVg6TSnWD5FUhhVZ5QT/2bmMu9F4LsQbDA6V5@Oup94Xf4qq1r414Jbtej@03bknZa17D@dwDgDxoNvisZALCy/uh0ILJMU710pKLP@iWTs@uo@Z@9bwThryNcVTsuIO7Py8tDA/Bz/LFcbGXmDRnyBLALL6863AWAJtEcdYqyPH1RjFUxQ9lVJViSfCabKuDdH8WGRTjXaW3FzbY33LG1Fcq8PqdbZ6MynlSvlbVmFySWaNBodKFn8HkyEZQ5/ypPVVvVFZTWYyydXkhV1iuSRFNfueuTiqHovXsejB8QyLzmyd23mg2y9pmduPej2y0QYJ2AZJ@hr0b2pNjsutILmp7Tmut/2nv2oL03XQtjw2sDwYrnZt3G7hDMyec/2E5ytyrw2HOpq@I4zrHoppzD2zV2PeNYpcbrHuXLPXh@fbwv5VbAqBlxOUDREseKWi6o/GLyNeaRybtmNythAZB6n8QhlOfzywoY9rj3qexs4ssmsZu@F6Prgwmj1ysaNvp9kRa5u4qkHmSqTb9h3nkgwHEZP/9Ffc6peMloQxiZ89Wf1HckTbpDyZ2hqGMwasfSAfTdcRURQkMuhXYxw5AlOb3F9FUx4yRwZOzPjGuJgNN8jdq52xzAFL4q4VNPErWx1ltXb65Zt6rlH5jg2y5n/@/ax6I@gmf5HZ2vTkNPOjlG@Rr6LBRQgOQ5NMXp3Ioli4P4K2AwRMJTZIKeim6vKNawe0tYL4zrwm41oyCbFRfcQ9CyCxPNCuRiqB5o2msqqM@RglczZiRdzaA2q/Di6@GYNMldBQFJOsTtgn1kNeyRhoPgNvnCB9tE0eVJ75q9XrUZuC7L7ZGtNC2lVBK6xXqDirzcpulVyu2XZwr0D93cWkkMtcTLYOGlnPJ87FxeSLXOFHQD0H1KfVx1lsQAev9m9WtWru0ydPnzJZvk2WucUDtPLVm5Ojk4Oz89r56zOg5i0vbOLQcQd6KCmQF8gaqOf0aRMGkMW1TO9@6RFIkOANoisKW9XZLu7rUlUpagpDUQWp5Yy8yp1BFBhHRFPfk3xRes@MhM9HEJKpYzEhRdkJMZLgmaQXlaBpn7ewXrC5g7YXUATtSRaIQqKRzCpApQxQ6YE0YvOl5DX4hDygGu8n1N0wFoEAWoUx5iMgkYK8sLw8nBduYeFv/wuUeAj92u9aYoJxZ4kxxl0lhohhMkpxWDt68fr0IJ4I2CnccQdjNRc3WXaobfG9O5y7HLFNxJdMNMzxhDl4IFs9dmV5NAxCfutgz9AH4YLNkdbTPZQu3HiU1foeSPJ2G0RTazpCyQYiXSNDJ27tlLGZnABiaUFHm2ayhHG9yvx2AZBc1wZIsfc88SrFI8ietGB/04WZ/eGf/Tnf03QxAvcfCfck9wze/kS8dcD9T/2QfB7e/nnwVoC3n/K3d1kk5fwGDl6agIhIwDdHJ8yjkRqSaKBPIqXHvg37TsuGsYI1AFpfEekwOi9WSJkQjlJ/A5SH6gKyo5BGuUz5mW5DQfP7UjaLqghOr2lkxWNO@DiNrPG/HeNuNOhKspvFzY08DFTMzJUPkCxqu2g2wgGqagm4UrqyhpX3LYPt7u4y2TP0vlnZLHOSZ1f1d@vy@wDRVYgrca2lziANJAlTQFhVJFNW9VRexaTYOJP5JGuUQSHhNQh9mkIOiKKit@0bZUKn6QhSAXvY5mREgn/qa2OgCtlkE2jyPYk@oAwA4rBxz9Qsl4eGIGg3F@F7LVoN8luMdobRSvIiJqu/YxejC7sh9s4xYJhfLmA5G9x/vGBDXcA9tfmdXMrsPiwsDXt6ZjtoMHQI2DKlkC2sZ/ObaqRNyQIU4Ist6BOAhDYDbdAwrQ/O0KvtHRx9dXxyNrcTiWImZ6MlWbK6m7rIaOl6I3AkZ7jeJ@qzw@zZy2eHPimjWIUT7RgjnG2fRXNRbrOYLsn9LbfAmc@bAuYyyuceCphGi5lDWpCahx6GZiMR97iFwFyuinpzW2/sVi/sxFz2nxbt0kxoa8hc4LrwaI9mki2QOUe@XdE5brv3NN@atCCHe5AD@1n@Hnov30sUbOIPNxT5FkwS2UoHptKStsS2CcquZXlWtJuGI@bjC7LGRzWPqIYZGtLcYkkUGybKMn/egDAJDoh0zAeytFlSt2EM41oGj@2RgObDXdrZBwOeo1E4RoJxF84Q0FBwSsMeEBXBHEXbojle3fUteoOQM3NgZc59fFBwhBuExM6YHpStb7XKeqU@YYH57l37ZDRv2LdGCm7amWg4nITSKCoWIL@Lu14m6u5OQ2wwYv4@oBRtJToZA71OnCELh/D7pu86hVEc2x8DcGADk301HkC8Dj1OTewlTPbKyUBioGPSR6KOm2dEGbRBuwi5az1z0ra60NMoahpE0hf5fLgJScddNHYS5DAn1ZdoSBIlzGdtnIpQTK/rmmW3zYmC9v6lBlIH/JPXb6@SqjzHA7R7S2xmas9u4/KFhT4SrTbcAjUjEHZ2AkEQbzs7O1rPk9C8GkYgkOPZyH0BTuhDlc5AHzJlTPvgPKYxelUuFDvtjVyVZarYn10zm6VSNHaBBwVojFJ2yGX1cZpWwe3jSrYC9Yy@nt3Gx0dryOp5TWuAmzJR2SrOPuyBuoHjdlUC1RSSlAgsdMDwV0KMrmGUhhjx5yplK9FOFoi1MJgacrdHDRBoQaVm1cfhxolIC@RU3dkpidqIi8MdBmyxu0BiANgFYs7XTYG@wkAWqIZCDGLtwaDUAoHy9GvTtqG9KsAzA2idTB8Dk7lq2j/vJB1ui6ccEhzF58LiFhCNb5c/SN70HdBnVrNlGgGXb6Hff3@BHX9HdP3T7H@f1bLlG2W1X5lmQRlTq8pqr5JPra@lUqv2mrJqozry@DEOnG9XQdtparImTyBSZrWvloGfQTuqrNrlVX1XWW1XCmuUAl5TKfUGEnznZbWbVf02u/oYtIk0@Li8dSqrHu1gy2la/hbwwxaymk0Dz9zgTi46xQSzX7VSKcRBW20iAt9lL85S1K9cnGVpjF4WSm62O/DFSFxXCWpi7vQVTkDhXQokehElulhObfqRo5vlF4TdqV1/jcYnjCbKTc@L8lc85OGCRQg0FE5CyCh8CyEQcKIAEfE1rasqCJPf/CaR34RR35PNdcVJPSnmyqlkMV9OJljiqZxdk1355mI/c8XMTLLe0Yvat42Ty5OTH6kXCtthycTesZzfkN@xncJaVkpk13KftrLZ9@/fgzrM6lWtqjXUeibZqCt8QLfFqltba@nN7bX002QzHEFuMVUpFFSotAtWZBdbur6W2ig8tcsQsoOfdZYHJ/5uwzfPikV2gJ@/@/d/9/O/@xn9/Zy@f2NZ1tBrt@Hr9Ngl@wifyw7Df3J/bEfcOrpbnY8KjDNA/axQ08ifJJPF9eTZO9yr@mQF/ugfPsEr/q6Qj/CmKPOfFSlRNRIfE/l8PjGlvya685PI4DlDL5Nln2w@X7jAvfjrmytPGVDVBCGKn1LpaQAjK29ty45DHj3IocicBGsfR3KZZPAjJfxTH/TOuY5/7LyFf6cj/Htz@eYy8@by1MC/Z5f497KFfy8@4t@5gX@E1XYlzQCp7yoVjgwTSM1@FntrWtN3IZT3u@8rv9uHfc5nIiVgMJeoVhupzO1tXXuXKpfFP4jBcvCGH@4CfBu3mczuu2oqVSe861VRgN1Mo8pLQ79a890ugE3t1nd3tWa1OqlmGu@qdSzlDf5MbvG3IEPLulhDZ2Wye8oh7vsgkd0Z/tHnBc@kfvICBi/n6cJuJlE4rO2lC2evnyXy8FYMXzFwHV9PD2r7x68h9smLg9rZwZdHbw5en4C/12hWnz5NacAKTwHfaqMOKH2RqqYqo9Go@ePmmob93g7v/nYCHGY@zQUu/iol9quT19nMLiD9ormDBTyl3DJAjMYnxsFKiXqirqSepJ7k@rmrXP4yf/nSOQ7/j48nEGBNch8cN9fL9fJtaDIsZ77OTXPTSW7gHOfb4DThLzcAp5XrTDaON4@fTnLdnJ2z8/kYuOX/g2Pn5bEDAB1INprkRgg714Fn9/j4JQDrQPYf4M/K5XITwHOSu4L/XD9Pn3fNHBRaxc2a8JbLXVxIdSa/N0H8afmklktqm8mk1ShuDr@9uS1sflsnba2406jjvtyGzNLJ5kU92Sgnst7FRZZLarmwIZdp4@7tbbO5XzuvNZtZnOSa7K6mnqYyT@FTqaZ2xeNJol0tP7koZZD9fEZMZHefXFTXM@jeTAH1C@C3m0195icECc@VCympXL99@xa/b6@vrrmLHNzv4m0Qij9vs@DFXegFH4yaXZQ@7pjMc5yi1IuNm1vosC6S5aTo0hRGe@Dl/MWk0GEFGYcNyo4KWkN@HXXTzSJTq9XNInhsbqsZJYfDCp7kQh4OhxeyRhMpGplRVio119WnOHhSNgCIslOsVC5k3W1eyPVCA9MWMzubzHEzO@uqrKrv8ru7kAdmUVDBW05OZMdNspvb6J9yc7ur0EfFP1VFTxW4hp5VVYEIahHeJjcK21V2FfQDL0x3c1tFJ8W7AVddURvq7S33g19F3eVQqyoQjoHG8F/pH3qS///8v3zNPFA8bhOoCttso6gqrampbmwq26kd8VdZAcIq8npyHXWcpJ6s15@ura9tbdSfNNa0NfwquxfVxoL@VgXNBxqy3/Qq@QRWLEoyrXwq5wtyEt2JRNkQu/77Tpet75Sxi8aEMnzQJSUZVGh1N2DhsP9Rq1j/jGqUqQ2m3t4AW/NAUJcVseJ0cTHJoYBhKiu3Kqs3Cf22nMAc2K3sRxetg@AryTItSco38qru1vMN@VZevWnd4rhiLa@SSlncKJfXNrh7axvc@TWVz7KD4lcO3BBierpRRjFUTiD3JoGQauJCqrTMLsCD0g6jDTRVLBZXsgV4TL7YPChM1sSnurbgs13YTq2lntbXdnawPhrk@WlFKuOCH19dlDMyb@Vse4ewSODSBH52zdUTUCvE39r@Gnfl8Xuw4klDZsOAcyvH2k4ft7c5nc4KeMKwnrVME0ZWZr/vnxABg79@@9pqmyuSZ8JncKKbY9O8Ho@vzeCzZ3n6hw/6kD6Tzg@//MkPv/wff/jVT3/41U9@@NXPf/39z38C37@C70/586f/ZqeIv7/@/p//bz/8xa/A82/g@x/h@x9@/f2//H3@pfe/he//FfH7W/GNxONfCWD9ya@//9lf/vr7f/oL@P4r8f3F7PeHP/u3/P//Fn/o/NUPf/a3@CNefvJTqL1/@Otf4v/P/vof/uMv8f9//1//4a//xT/8yb8mx59zx//zr/4N//37P/jJ3//jP/37P/h@ye9P7vz9/gH@3/9X8Hk4ng@B85Byfa7P978VPr8LNcJcgAeA0/74h3/5h8Crf8bf/gm8wX8Q9EfBSyyEv/xR@AIQ/pcFif7419//6V8Gb38YjxgLAyB/BGF/EQv7ox9@@fs//OX/8MMv//yHX/4Jt61QuHSgCSuW39wIxI8qKXTUCYhKkEyZjZ10LZ3J3z0MSEDE4gPiYcTNh8SDiDzKCluRCvTEH@HJVsg1WZOK6zhayvBPint@WkUdkl18korwnvqUxUNAWPaTCL3ArSh5CF3foNAcqMM5DC3iqx8aQQWXlZ88jWnpHJG1T08ZRIbEkcgU8QlHVPinPsXEO6ak8JUAcfiGma0E6VcWEOYJewrB0BVSb7iLv/gCPs9g6CZGcJXqNqtIabZdYVX2DCNW4J3C0Unv0HHiObcVaZ89wzEneu8DhfgAGkZ273GEnKLoVR6VVSX2HcETYCoc0HcSeKb4@z48vxOxJxJBw3@hiKIbv34A/KQY94NX7H0IjviReAwezPxHlJY4WsZ4mG6C/ywEJOCkJCBDKh0dYAVZpEIvKXhNzeUS4DMTlgrDmOhEY6BSbA7gXYExb2k2IVsIRWCwNHSmmH7oghz90MR8kiAoSqBUKk4wTBkvVEpKofnamsh0LbVG1iprn/sROFEGC8lxxydK77Ww5FG4IfYhVMKXJ0hR3DBvDJK@cUqlynf5jS0JnvQ@xpOlxBlHwIF4bLC2Cx@MXb3JYEOVqmcH5xB2fszyhZzG6rnGzcZWYaO4USysb24Wtwr5jc2djc3i9noun9vMFQuF/M7Gxs72ztatVP0Rm2js5OT3MrcAaJLJZAsIkVXyxa3ytAIpyUuq4tpChet705sMqHqIwQWpmjdoAoCzJjc0UfYIPkx6JLFH4AWfzK3EjwcCHK@xALTcxMSC1NFxWSxb4BF5fOlCzhd35BmKq7gxU7ow7TbPTtpir0/g5/Toy@fnkef5QW3vubTJnh2/2p95FEWkIntxcHgevG7xUD9pMQDxzcGLF7Ov4oFq8AorbqXTmqbBDz7T9KGntvrOj5LXlndG8mausCXn082pCbrwTSZz27VaZn4TxjAb8uMEqOB47hUQRHqJVgY7eW4eanloBwcprm0yQ2zh2aDj4XJPeKAXOl2r24Ou@doJIniedx1MELz1ZwOCWYG3rKXr@P3cD2RgRj@juz1GPA/ymwvpz0eXnsMYYoBHYOE2iRFObVsdlpM05NBCYWe7uL2zXthOb@9sbxTzm8ViOl9I57e2t3Zy6Xwuv53f3C7u5NPbGzvrG9AYILS4syUlgL@sTjYLDTMvy/S0bAPPatnFQ28crVeVEm2zg/aSbKK0VZZoBx7jbSavb1/kGCSUJbRcWptU5MIG2nSt51lelmSdGSxxeLiXOzyU5Wf4glNTezlZbuNLcTuX23omyyaF7EGDLUCiHr4dbOIclixb@LJXOzxECB/wpbCNMGT5kofwl77/sgXRbHxZX0cATJa/DcDlALjDMdqmVCP@kss925PlMUdvG/4gXo2/bRCyB/iCAZjokIfsQZgsf@knAt1Ilk95PJHVc7@8tZosH/GXWg1BfEWFL/JCfY0vNfpAIhfegHFluQuOrgvjQ1lugRPZV5YNcBlTHfwG4MKNYfZIl@UpLweWRJYnFFs3LmW56ftDPoDP8@d6b9Q2u/wzdfnTgKAjCLIm44PD1pdftrrdljutHXx5SkFfffVc/zAdu61uSyRsNeHjYCoIuhxMZz8mBjWben9x0NcQZM8ENadNkzBs6t8CZuLTxYwGza8w6CsIWrQYIQDCZwCRW/h5NoDnM73Fg/wPBdFz0mrJZWRZbDodhRhXT9ODTlxTbxiuKXuK/oQkUwmlktNRcunxtpopPhlvy5tbcmkNnvITeR2c0DRYLpljTE5eyLJa32k8kbeKcin55Ekm@Tj/hMlbO3JJ3toCKa@Wb7EDUNSbjjJJTyo58Mhmd7FBYxOEZ9D7iM6hsC2DqARvPwJv@UHbhZ4CpDKDbyYjYfiwIjCWmYIHP6JtNi00KsnkViGZVJNlSLsiAy4CFTLfxiL7GMsgMwDjnQIkd83R2LVZrnw7l7N7WfJGuosrzZRDicmb0JWBN56mOf95CmOWdGmtVdyt/qO5z3/3jxZ9FvviR@Ld82ZeStxKbTybZWOnLCVupNub292qn@XXbDrVU/7AgD1mrJtalVaTWPLkelwXrlVq3dOaP5FV24Px2Lqz4SRWV1elxO55VV6Xj7VmMG1dzdJKyAUuk@CSgnbR3F1J/VZz2hmt@tRfBALUs5Jrot11G28r4HPL20WsiS7zEqnf8gOZSBWAKZVxQlBOYPMx@s4YV@rYBS/Q7ncJmntmJzedsU2GN6WXqK8oeumMTtCqN4CHv3tl9W@21zNVWi9WgIVviSuMY1rLkxK2I5xARxgcj8zJSAE1pyjT0DhxOzzbebf1bvvdy9fHr48Pn@ZK26VtIvrFhWCUdD6ZT1I1PoW@yjo9uEdFbYJu@ckp5r@zvyonSsPk@kZyPQi8qCQ4FcGNbUOp1/MNVl9vNOrAjw2mwmulUniSL26nNkr5LaYmqoUtzdOniYbYs6JsbKnwQrORhXzibfxzHXu5ooUzKbH98v0nmiDkJ@5bBXJls4yt3u7ewn/1tr67e7uL1p/wwH/@c3vLw@kfC@C/0CP8xOKFccLw344btWai8V1ml//v4s/eMSeCvFmU1cT7ShV45F3zXTMhJXaYXKB6TWX5jOSQMa60rNn0Z3pr@Pcu9FgDJWwteDN31zxWrMJYHfyy2eyF@nsF0Gh2dja3NxPSb4Bcd9jfQWhgkNIxTdcbDxZZpNRc66WO1jp2YJUCjpfjj3ik6lP/UgVf@WGo/aDJFao/UT@hEUW86C6SuN/Uy@L@APSVJHRZdDEO6xDn4ST9iOy82RpuFMVtUKp0Iz0CWGNjRFsL4KcsSY/Qxh1fFT9emj32RipOP@RU6dEjIZi9keaNmggcEwnPTL4s3UpIHr3d9hgdaoxrS3zvlI4W486Qn6jQnzKeyKO2wTU52vaE@UYQXmMdjgWUZo1RjoQ5Fo5n/4hHa407iMrh0YsDSANjnQ7ZhojUstvCI7@peCsdlQX9C9AAz72tCEpRdIwI4MCTd9TqADdoGQrFTLE8hnfIxgRipVk@TZikWUckrONrA5Ij@A6IOw8A89wVXgK21hTZijIIfKgQQEIsHXWT6NDdrpEWtYeHDtYbKrvxt4EoGMp2WSHcpyJgQWXw63oooTFoi@OLKyGZCVq@kYaqLfPtBEoQT/iEhLqV1kbpQZlX1bAsfa0YoE84rlL@bvD4sfFuWB80yuqgMsJnKjWArvtSsXiUtVFlUAH2GNatRnlUT6WsRmWgfq3gO54Sjv280Io8VZQNSm5XABe02fHU9Me6nfnObqQP63YKUB6n135c@ZjWKznUZ9JWJZ/up7@t5EU5IM9R5WPKLuu78EU7q9hWDdBWUno55oVJLpV@5WNdb6CC1IeEqdQhFAbw9Or9VKqhQuZ9CJxPWO4/fqyn@tVJuZ/JqBjr3fqTw/oIHI1UBd9Lir47efKxPob0JQWeFcimrwLykE7Q@jbAHfArA415nYaocxxJf5sAeoNKZe3HT9Z@vFZZWflYn2QGjTQnfykXcgMiP0Hky5GtMMraj1U2QxJablPkL6zSFxoIRzltpVJA5PQwkpJjuPZjCBmmUj7Wtygv6RIR34YPOUxs3@AnBtNxpmSSS8c2e3T6@aiNG9kgbc0zLEtE5zsQhxYMpHXc6Jqmo8F1ioFh4lYjDLyYPHki@VmLHQOQMwqXlsl0HJDTnRYurv3RDVl8X/R98nWRGPZlbjASpWOqYcy7vhlpriSaqMF5rlHHKCgGbnK3ZS6x@D4REDYkPSAOSQ@Ml0EpgkQSckLErIhAqC2/giAVyokO39OPp@F6KJ9Q5w5aPogQjgY05gVoWOkPFZJNwE8WuJi1S/mBA5qK9AgKgThgGawGq4IgY48fM/G6W2H5whb2BRgN431I5THSHKaQ@QMwBRiI5QfgUZSHlAng9ghDcB9ULKON3y0jsY1RgQSpD2m@m1Gj3YzK2Pb4Jl6km8rRwLp49OhDqrIhEIJ/GrJAegi7/U1CdPcltnf88uT1@cHpy9oZ/MIQbjt6@r9/w87cvRpDvC@jZdm0l8fQT/PmN18ZjCmgD4/wbFK8QKvNvnr9ghUKr/bTeKQYkD7BZyuhQy0FkEyPTm72NMftZq@tSysbv5YP7zqibUN0CWDGvyYA0aHOuR9uLQ53Fns4GwaduTgHKXYi/8D0PHFdSMa/go1OoaBN1gPcKwytUFwvQhbZvlEpmTDjAnWaDONdq2vRvVo9DiCWng5aH/Hk1D4kvBakrY905GhpZzuXK7FcGh1531HwHeu@Y8N3FH3Hpu/Y8h3bvmNHOPI@5DyHDIPi9fXN0LkVOrdD507g3MiFzhDCRiF0rofOjdBZDJ1hbhtBbpvbBJclfGpS0zVdDMtvbPtheDQAjIrQswhg8rOeG4BoYS4mJN@Y84T8tuOeWzs5kdFR9hgjFQqb4TtIHz9uReFYpTkeaZ4zfxOe0FdJfPxHDHvguiCVDiZ4DxIwnVpiuFVSkkDsMqNv6qAMmCPQUiqHwP@mWuJHCLjTUrhdEiFU8sE7JMdj@CFNnq704uyzILiwKJhDKyyExs9gYAFhIntNBZIcy1Ksp@UQN2J@UagrKGCRoktiFHgMrIP45lQ/z3N3vDDL9buzjAFcmOUcUhxucVEqpI1CwCt@Uur/CVrFz4/rKSbVNqgB4gJH4oGZCsWzJCo3@ZL86@9/8X@wX3//s1@xH/7iV//vf/if0f1v8effgc7CCkGEn/6M0Uo7/PwLRuvqtMYfJqL46yX5h1/8El7/p3/NfvjJz3jQn/6lnN4IAEEIeoUpf/5P8OcP8ef/lNPFIOLP/5hHxCRy@laKqVYKxPrp3zAGuSGUANgv/ooxOQUKhiI4r87beCOy85wDCMhQJ1djNpz/4vU3QOOcmpIBrnjLh28prAA1AtzV8UbCsO2BOsOXjVBKG7rRw93FwsvxUP8xUIVxPK0L/HbdBqVHTHQkofR/wEosmcI4KppZt3GMQzJclF@UWw5DMW5KzgJ2eIWGAEWXAwWYwPBWAv6mkcDU03DYQiPSPOcRQd9XeOOp34HIPmfRXSmSyMtPjTMx4t44ujzHH@oi02I3xI@goDtjJLH9NR/JMCZuZqoNcpn1gSFjuCk9mpQ8zMEQqgSSBfRGwuILUSE9Cy6sOdFsDo4PZxoMflqgYl5GJVKQUYXJ8j1xkdIivooa13o8PsdXRKjnSuuN2Bb3RZHlH/3oR7IU8cshD7lthSBECsVFRhCUjwcVIkGFSBDgzGGSrCkWCjM4UMeBcjF@nANPFhFR8WQhc2HL8esB0YCxIJ8pTXf6Y69XmQdNEjku7OaBR0DmGxXRTi5skjlVJqtzCQBmPE1lti4Xg87NxZmvqMUpkdoxn1htLYcUSxNpFEQ9aZZKQc3ldxbVXDzDO0DnG6kHZlTI/Y4ZZR6Y0Wbx/oxmqxXTxsAvp@/9YscXE4GED4Hxhp@IdVDYNf4CWC8UR4ixS05FhSFPTQx5WtcOUxZcEAj@Wf8M0ditgG7kZFEcxLxyRiafHng6dGDI4aAWHLlWeNG94eIW367tuKYXPbrC4pt77SQenmI4XRt6tTSeZWqJKy9xeZ4fkxXvV4KeTWihe/ymYgTNCYWaZ7Np2dao2QTls99RQwLiq2bgjsukhFccgyuSXglU2@Oh4uCZzCP1fpik7/Jk55ZxqRwPRWASMqkxGNAZZh8GX6yHl595DicJFpFfhwYaaWuk0MFpPWfgdE3bwXNjMPUM@KMQNiKkD4eES5rpaWZEMBKDaMVI66pI@vVnJ2VfF/D6Pj99IQ4gRow0c2dpjJR1F2TXXJodT@bnd/b5@J5F8T27G9@O5XqjWZzJE2d78Pl5Wa8rIQSIGKKxfj8aaXFU1Bw6MVQCb7x4kyd4MIpt0zOg@0NMaxC1JqJrHeCPdPDm0d5KgfibZfS/uwL95AcPrT5SZs@mIG8GdE8eDdE8OijPNkwFoh@pamgSFskuYO39B@YlBjo0wkszmQSXjRt3oWEOh6btBfZVPuB7eB7thub4noyJKjxwAU7uVZpdFpZX0X6zbfb1qdlWRMx0BK5f4lNTb5O8eljBUdCR0HP4batKLp2PqWJ0wAJFKi1hGT19parL2YpHsQLuocU4wvBoOf1o4m5WNOMkaIWvgTguSNAEncFGJ98Np8MpP5Slz295F3KU9z@8Jl/hWTX3EgTowG8jzKfDbNW7xOepEhTpAT1CEFeLF5m2NvvdlgPa@Fwdfh6J7i8pzTIEiSp@Lce0k2U1bt1V4xGu8HmSayUPY8n7mO7BPBdhNQ4sFGF7n9eFzEHe0/t9w1CiELnPnTXm2HMyAf2wxhx7Sa/SXCBQg5Qk6UZ4lVSF6xeqZIHzCJ5X8HwDTwQIY9AmZyi/bKjX@lNeFDLQhxGtRfjUDdRFI1RUo@uIkViS78aJ3NsgT2NpnsZcnkYsz6AFxLOMRJKMWJaiFrB67qqCvtkZLZHOGIQjd3jcJbbhYzu6i2uvN0krWbLSLHmVLIFATprJ0oECQjnZTpb2yeElS2fkuEyWvgZH2LaSn5Ilv1lgBBdeyfEU/YUIx3cjWdpT1FsJr3v3/Hy1ZCmoU4jzhL8SRW759GpLrPo7wayqiVfpolKZZsgxHjwcLFa9kaZvDv4pqjjYFAJXKqywRpFxABLrNCI9Bs8Hug0NL0N2lUXdR8mfmhLzG@EcCoSnKpFJFeSSMcmjZCIZF0YcMQylyUd4AoIoN0uLMWL5uZHZfeiI3C28xBiIHc@fqKeRPtBWKLwOkaOTOP0wvV9fcRC8Ah@GJyZehuccOn52hBEaA6gL0EKivk/eUSis65lDMnntR2tofo4AKzHjR@G1RGAjMh10ONRNKbOhM4wzCYXiap8VTYMf0SiRe2eSkVQQLXNJMHmLkqFgiDZ@9a7iRNIhajERhIH1XIO3sqBfIFmMQaGsi2iqvPEBChGZ06ZTq0xk233hpHhc3KSpr1jWDflpeZYkueJiEhJruC98rI947uG6DO4W/7zhq58SVHDAEQFEUga5cPnqfIb@7nD93VeofSLMZLBIsV7clc6r13f2sjOY98Ns5ysQA9NsX12oHAU5hCSH0UFEM7@L1@ZUfLx1lCv5PNMA@oy275MtGBPcQ7fZsQWHhVqCexX3vMSJ2cvCckLNayT9K81XWjTMScDhBQ8wDYt2N6684IuqGEOwj4bHZ1ewG6/gaOUhPCqAO0Ny3spxpw2tUwRtm84eClcu@KqDg1ZiwZGvEU8Q92S/Fphogcdx83T/@NWLb6DT3draUueXIrDVQtqwH5fuXCYIhi2FNJ7ahwcNk@1Ez3FHKxe2PG9SRh6gDOi0bsPZT7RxVciyiDyfabuQjseNUFTAugybgR6TSqjq6NhlW4Ku/I4bZU0XQHz1FuidptEarhohd@CCTrNJ3VezicY5zaboxbBqgmWk3yTEpbeF0F5DSsStmUjj8uaOxsIJgDGaVoQTcOLQK26HkgA4RyM/dZBqbI8s39gB54doy66/lq@s53F24qgT@BAeaJShFDZwCFso4jEbPBXGxolPMq0U@axwRQfPfveGjk2n99KJiKS240n0nj/1SmiP7WudzEB4LnQ6SAQjbpDlr4s5Nj@W3eNpcd8cTSH7tEkzs6vRik9hB4Ycl9aQH@oamH54KiUihMlGC2jc6psDQOkMeHfBbPJLC2qld2h1u8BIWXFxEzdwOdchacbpZPb8w8oS7I3et9r@sdnCJoyOrBfzwEBOJXbanMcKm6BN7aSBsuEXCItmMgxPlMuRkRbFgu8WPLa4czsdSbuiTNX4M@9/VIS3ojSxZvmGYsvFS5qudDtCZ/p8ik5Ni0VLkgORlUv/fDNJHHRZoXVKDW3UhoqckP2Dz9DJzSb0vuGfw6bgCYAl6ZFNggctwJjBbWtAwbVRaaPlNTUwSbXZF2y9QNfQQ36kpVK2AIOv7MWgQxgkRWS5dZ8QMPIXbfkLXEyUHiVQFnJew/Q@K6ObDtAOeZmtCHB8QQWbMm8C/ksx8rIOQ41HCzJeUeQUQEnJqhyDBPHF6scjLnnnk4JQBPHwuabYpuvaFE26AlHC6MZNYUZcvsOwlyx70XwwZteLg6mooWZH2K/xa2rS8mu0wCrxTKjv0PBcSxTd5VnZncn75pr0QDtptkabQjuxjkZ2MXGAxopl34UA9SjEoShnyPzrC68EX8Ah7YMEMpHFgkK0Ue/FjSiCdtS4/T/XKEe6FCUfxQYR7HggUDpAz7T8BVqtPoaE1MVCf6cuUpty5Vh6QM4b2mTJLWc0mZIKq2OEFAfBaxP9A9tXiQzefcF1x0ndeja/ndvcIftpZqdH6UF9p5FeMyoyM0eWbg@8sXvdvuw6vStQFtjwQ2tiTD9@y1hxg@GuksJjvsk5v1nJ0ikQW3QMwA4djrPqnzFAW@UvZMZoTyweaZBkLNiJVF7BsyHgk8afklye41K2NvC5kBtRD@qbjYpdyZUHdbtRtlMpdZSqjFL5lIIej/NqGSQtn3apjxpkFZldYy9900U8xxLnVp0OO3Fso@ckPUZ33UXX9Gh/md@ABvow2p6uYNThuFGfDvKTPog1xHkv7IX1mZSW48cbTYcmisbA6rOPF4Xiz6Px5kZ5PhxL@OgRmiiXhW4aLcCNNBy3@pYBMojoiSoGmiuWSsLo3mDItyCg0M/inhwX6IEUDC77oYYznIrEFo/S9MuyGwFZVbDvUtMPienHagFPNvHUcRei8SicvLHoDEBT16NyrND9wrSDfgb3SahltCJnK36Yv6MC4yPf0L6GJqh/tAsCHrtMRCUbY6YKi17yrVtoVECqWjXJgx59GA@G1L9rHF9BEbxSpTnULTdIqXljvJRPYXkkhuUjjTWAjlvcsXcFimW0avy6wIkFWtzG8iC8EzoXFxA2dLwzDGQjLu4gvLZDaR7xO3sU6AT5xBVHQ6SlYqiiqoFweA5VcpgsMZpnKIMXdTnlSOgHCMWyLgkeQPBAH/WWBPcQ9thbFuxCMN7ksyTYgmBuc7I43IFwrkktiTDCWTRg1@bIaY50q69wg2k0tb7lAlthqZRP2IAFGK8YXh/x9EyYnrMVXjuc2WLsBe2T2IpHQJZWROPB95BbKBTPTlA4X0Ty5DRhN@zezMTkE5C4STmB2MX81bUYfBZBANofiFI2H@5nzms7KGiMfzTodrpY20Csdfbp012YCUaM81@@4XMfryGc54yUkFMrhMMvGgnrlSf6KBItTiNM86PSzddBw3L4jbIQihDetsJ23bFAX4SkKmo5oTcOKVX2JPSpew1WCqRHSEfeLO6nY2GOe3DESS0yzVqh03g4VXXke0ipQ4/cCoUF7sPSy3Pk9ILYmXjsKsQOqDnDZ0aMZ0Qr/dzCPqw0CcCPGjXRpswFrQGqYVUguAA9nddrVCZwYKvJEvfHa1GsODBrCTC@X7EJAEa7gAP2bL4Y9/tEy9a4zQ/I@VxhI01T@DzKbUgmX1g9hE7/BRoXEk502WM8KT4uktgC0sxFD8qN9KrONrmZ4nFJv7hwdW40lnySRBzZPD8R1z2BXrLEcizYGFNmt/fLod@OMjdh9cX0HU9ZLiv8Svc58SEseLuE0PcyWbwIhQaLUXxM904P7@2SaJPn4k4pXLpo@j7@tBZv20s1MMSqHA9HnDlAPwAU5WiqtNC5qqHoFLtbmyNfuUmHWhhdh05cASp7WYqKcxzOHVLnHfUNtuYQRaIhaCmIGqbrY2Z1fN0W1GA/nWY0sZo5kZGe0Ka7jtNWfIVJKAwEwbeAhkhpvl0oUKu4ehlmD9kJpZd1hRW13@@WwWdFeFG/Ah6ofAreRCTWutRsythsIvqN5dH9QRSOvRFk5a/u4GQQlz6sNOuPsQMV6NHCRL7Exz1ftDNYyHnqiWPiQd7TbZx4o6OcaGi9K6N/UBEYpwoD7XD/MNXB7YJZBr5HWuwevokOXayypaFOHFS6P8uklgNsdndlzCY8lOM3iZXs2HPpQlPTvmJ4o7iUYKbNT5Av4S2MmW2ciMVLFIU0oXlvmuQBNoGawtw027xWxEWLuEtbViW@548mhfISHh1B8/J986oNWj@3iB863oR@pzBYyGnj4cihEJER7Q1kn6xP4X71HK3SihGDQGeX4IRxFFy/4b5TPheVyXMFKY/HYqgREHVMSQJXvpBlrD9EVMzX1RuSp5m60UMkkPc@8eEUVBdx8q3k@VWPe9mQFLg4CM4@t@Id0twcZkHaiTeldyg@vufRwX1oChH5XoxTJJpwxZC@4wyRyXGqDdPvAgE44R@dne8fnJ5q4oBZviKAqwh8nhhNMGhDoLgkVUyT4moAbsfklfIIC4uweX6VEDjJX6IRZivIhE3hGsnJaYX7PXkJMnl6mytGEF/l0YkktJws3jykZU5YTQ9Bj0LahcmUSLKMn8yPHCHFo3upoRsGGtq@NAcOYLxH967nOS0eheRAJ1LEzz8V5O/VMc9GgDwPz8yFZ2LhGg/nSIWxNKPnhpFK0Uhy4iaMd8vkMFp6Lq8Kg0IfvaLdO5rjRvAu3xXX02CQZoWRq0FVcq4MAnZjAZlIyLsFtc9DVmJpAgYPwus8XPB3QdR8gGUs7tN4/viURAWZZOMqTEJmuFSzrT6/uDcMIQnLcNsKT471TWzHG6WYEBHiJANiAm8xxWZbrYRQUnlf4lCbkau7T2VNTEk9UWbRUPldn7MNa0EbiVCJ8kwR4SbUk0A@FLwSAUEwkdGY33KrfuKpSDyNgMVYK362kr8TO97AoWizTbyC0@af8Mdv7HHk/HiJxYGPOOYTXni@khUnEAndFXkxmeLSZOSOTe4pCnVHLxLmPZ2FuFhIvHJwBGr06LJaP0@Tr7d1nLHdXgnkRFRQ@JJiju5BiKB0GCHvs@@yKsTAW@k32TXpS30AWmHfnLAa6tQ6HaYkxRYz8XpZDw@JhAK6zBsPh31L7Jtj17RcxsuZLxRxsSeEGFEaNOkIDXB4/DS6xOIjJNLYMUK@RjuOMMDDC4fpokqGN2GBaO1YAHKkSTV7yu/QxG1mBb6kaLKxx6@cppu1I0jwmuOtJ7iXVJP8hVte1A5v3/YIVCAouOPyC5edTkmSfm9sGZd7X7JCLreVz63nIyTzp6pz2vpG9L7kIKCQy@dyxfyGJO05wyk3HVEMFWFtZBBgmr3Ajv4N8KZ5hTdVSTXoMSginifpme6V2dYk6dRs0xxwa0wUQVbGq6vplAraR48@oFvheUJ4mauX5je2AofhE/tnfjaAQYbLaQnXaIemO7BGfCXXueJ3dvvr0h0HbxiniWhcEub0wEQDcwREWVNZHCXa9y9wId2FtuMDNXRxoabecq7onA5BBtBTLTzeiBZYJdykihCimfHb@CKYQH5GX7cGyE4LEMBdLCEFfASgaO2xYd6Jg0RIfCYO/k2hbcegq9B1v2ayIP0caivQ3E3XAukbEphqhZJFcIcKPn9@dMbOjg/P39ZODxi4T06P3xztH@yzZ9@w8@cHbO/45Bs6GpU9P34B0uWM1V7tg@@r89OjZ6/Pj8FDrp1BSpkCpNqrb9jBj05OD87O2PEpO3p58uIIoAH409qr86ODszQ7erX34jV01l@mGUBgr47P2Yujl0fnEO38OE25@smkMB07PmQvD073nsNr7dnRi6PzbyjHw6PzV5jZIeRWYye10/Ojvdcvaqfs5PXpyfHZAcOCSftHZ3svakcvD/Y1yB/yZAdvDl6ds7PntRcvZgp6/PbVwSkiHyvlswPAsvbsxQHlROXcPzo92DvHAoWuPSAeIPgizc5ODvaO0HHwowMoTu30m7QAenbwe68hEgSy/drL2pdQOEm5hypQL3uvTw9eItJAibPXz87Oj85fnx@wL4@P94nWZwenb472Ds7KTHpxfEYEe312kGZ4MwZlDTCAWhAO7mevz46IbkevzqHPeH1yfnT8SoVKfguEASxrkHSfCHz8ipcWiHR8@g1CRTpQBaTZ2@cH4H@KNCVq1ZAKZ0C1vfNoNMgQiHgeLSZ7dfDli6MvD17tHWDwMYJ5e3R2oEKFHZ1hBICJ@b6tQaavqdRYT4AXdwKzSj7npqk62dEhq@2/OULMRWzggLMjwS1Etr3ngubQlrPSwiW3Oxfw5lf5xFTI3Yfw7B3vH4DGxw/rk0P/19DpbMcX72Jh0NEEgfAqVkGpr2q2zda428RbtHFoHiTjK9gDr5vGUy9VvMnkQrrjbECxUE4JEolm802tCePcs2ZTTT8kZQyN@1KIXe53xVJFGfuO3qZhfmxuKUqo6mNxlk6aH2wRnWt5HEw@qCybbZsiGRqHIGB/mkgc@gTA2igZyWpEt1kkS1pijs8V0Ylks5NF/vKm48GP/Sl84X1DxAOEM7dbyGZxDEto4MlyLMAfMqFD18TJa2QHYHUoS80zzcuukotmh0N@MUGl@mko7giGgV1FvSd5y@zOJM/Mpidk0ZaHlBX/uB3/GBx@hSm@CZIxUS@aSyVT@NQePVQfG8oIlEKVZ0WGQsL6RHnMk@P@bT5XqJaDo1rouLWXtR8dvcXBXK6wUZ7xfx7487aFVn14diD0d3VK16DH8waPAA3MwuEXkMSa8iXVbDaSBrQy0ieDyHgWUA8jXVtt6FOxq@6Z1K3jCUT8OIZoeuiMXWsSxR7E8JentZfPXh8eguREbDe2i1ubZUmcaOSOfpTmz28wHzolHakLWvS1BWoaBUVayR7oPYdzhxFGTk/E2sOIeMK3X2nkiVe4BjuTuY7Azy/j00BYXA9PcLLxEDMZD2FyZX5J8Yrk8@vClikYQIkVVcXS4E30qOHroCoRDxh8F3J/SrU2wR@EHTR/v4kHBRIMJFjMHAxHU@BcGFyQ3JMPfYNOGtuQ2RZG0WSfj4e6b4PECYMyk6xc0caR3gRvR2oR9FqsaGyvVO2UEpBYmcXCPwSPjrSELE4cz2/B3NMCnx8JfgPnN@LwRQzCo7RqozMg42GQMuMfjsjnnEXDEJAb1QpU0ePHQU67DCdSVYEUn/@PH80XbQ2ECjdoYDOAfcujgM5BCE1CP02q7IZzKp6agnDKgmPFO3DuouIIKGX/yBnx7p/Qxzis8MA@8roO8pD8KN/4UQJyxsj0O9GD4P83pMkC@Lsw4AToIbVIDlv22HwgJQkqpxWMXoko1rVvMRYxUwupGfX6JgRzG62YXlAwYYY34QtLQAJRO1Pf4xt@ZKuygADI5DivEW2/we3nPR1GTk@p7T7iK/2ubQyGin/gqd9VzMFtpEnnSvsmcvii8iX8HItk9wLPr3tK@2hJZuCAC6RYa8q@8GQOI5UnmYOFzq7RpEfQyok1kQx5v4WH7JQTTctv/BNhYRT2Mm0/9BZU0eWHqQbLIXhmY0zg@ysgvgAh26dogQXZIM8qIrqw3GhJT7P8TPTieDo5iEDql9k5mT97eofGzNgVCVtlNIrGLBHOF21xJmbLHF1jd9Hn0MlGO4TGlC/ITBwzEXORgRrhC19VA6pTJ3sdYE/TlMivAfav7UsbL7cw@RSXH0OLnbAZ3eKusZc6HbbZf1i55TDzFJK1Gs//yCa7dYOvV@LUHI3cIRcc6X/hhRQBjfMatUvoh0Iq6cYleso@j1rXGWsCD8orI0runxkJYwY6EXiR0n@7dECAvDJjA8vkCzuYRCrxjqzyha@@oIu33cD1DbrEPHMFCgXIgQ8azAo1CFFGvQmNNOdbG@EX27aAxqcl0Jyur7WWPh7odkcfWP0pWZ1@cHp21rPH3hAv55ZlOT4biAetoAk64D4y2VvLbjvXHnsGzQEnks5evT47iU/8RWa@9vjMF2NfQR7sGeUszYHv4J4Uz@mMoGrMMpuK63bccLqH5gnFTAtNa03RAzf@uMRAkO8g0Iy/fPWafWnapgv64AnZXLIXlmHaID5AmSIrTK/HJQ1GP8Tcz0Tu7BB1F5rZKTPTokmdYG5PEhkIaGlkLQWaIiDsimOrcW5@CqwemRPU5gsclqvtTyr1nKHYbYGTpqhs8inOzriflvBs7LdH589xMM4H5jQ3A92aP9eHc4lcdRrwyVoojKvboykQRZqdvAG075u70RhttgCI0nJy0qBugHfitHHar@9BUfGuJCEFqAeBpmpaV3gYL03DPaSOyM5WTJuFdCuL/atpfjywLzpitSeFtZfGM9m1NCvusHMTeZed9HUDRljsbIzJ19dBD3zmeCOM@rLGWK6Qz@cz@XWcon19VtOoIeDXP6FVko5enhyfngMhxRFEPmMEfSYSnw5F5dZYQI4MHo0KpX@PAtmPDxKz8J6Ihyq4f06CXOYrFnJJhro3dJzuhRJ6cXWYpmRxSt5x6WBW3G0DLBRrjpCrd43Cly@NUE4R6Gk6Gta/35y6lgBP2i1JCd4jbn3gqz6uh76nxOQHAsCckB@kcmlk0BbHCkGdDMxBgL018nt3nUeQZs@UDQjG51KBOZLpJGpJQD01Cqdtoo2Eh6czDbwrwwXZol8By6EJi7/lCHiGZJMalEZvWX0L2gDgZfQc7HC4uPIrgqYgoifOSlTjwVmG2CERLgtOg4LW1XYGQVSOlSQFm@2E/9CbGg5LdGGYjSMtb2iabTqJajzkRy1huAatvA89B9@GVwrPYJISObKbdEHY4JF3dIMX7s3HvZQtXueSXxrgKn/75nkPh/UcEJTobESNFE/EVRaMsNMM13lVqnYdGALTqkiIJRspAcQwjYtSgBXUNzEEuYhd0rjdp0/1PbvPEhPSYY/eMB6AsPiqrhkP8MFj2YVzLgJn0kqAwMwWTh8Zvg@Ju2NzYPEXLC/aneKmNIWXEQo3VQNiHlp4RDmfG3BY18FfjKz5FONrhCatEc5tDMXrC/MAbzZmfj4mxAoOaIvELCyAmVkIc30xzIyAKRYrj@wr2hCHqYgteCn4aRsOyEckRFj8Lx1f9NK2vb7DF5iC0nf7TgvPxQRJAbnhY5oOKzbqTSOwGKGjoXyTZvw8z12/SAJ1sbfJ113YLrQPs8p2/RmL6oXNK0oEVHhboj1hjPouak7kxB/Rosgpxw4HRa1j5nRQRI/7guxGsLIAKXzkEgtbJlriROOLnONJBrEk@ZkkArl4klYsSUEKd4LP1C6mQNGPz3jJfL2ErJKoBlglqKCcNNAnfHSTow1@NE2DR3LHdhwWGoJBMGLdYMGeQYzekMIjMGLL9jwP/5VM8MjiW16V6UjRXPw8qYlvukdigGLFwqd0zIqtiAKpggz0EhyvofrIiHLtUhI7IqmCAvMAKVZsF/dqKdFc1BJLDHW@aoixPOzYolnXiQa4Si/D3xpTRAaZKLI8Eh5bIEQhEJ6OtqjDUJZXiy8Hc1LYM9NbRMBBDUpcfpPJGO8GFCXWrnzJHcDkzjnZDaDQn4OjnCS@v9oDvY77Yo8SEQ1nqPDhMfFCyTMnMDyjNWYCQf1PMGMtPPmZEYH0EMjXw5wbfq8RL8XS2LNdyaI4kV4loMJdkX1iB3RaGnl5b0OkwzkElHc8eoR0L3CSWJDO74KTHicZaSnWiDaTO4bFJVScbBGhy9OmFwjgeJX7yKVnSiVFjooRJZztRqRYzxljEiXyhtfgsC/4QcEckCrFUiH9l1U4mjtGG/bSeHkeT1T7Mo4IYPn1fhdbBJH9er@LLXjkSLXfzRb@WdEBaSn9LF/EaoKTAI0SxYiB5pSiMsgPmERjTWZiEULTRvSsGLOvLMA2IlXFXKc0pyoFJBJHw8XzoMeEV0xCbOSOsSMQrx7URiMsLfRxxqXZDk68EKUPhkhVOd4l8NqcPegJC@3nQHXUUPFKkiABSGw@CSbGzANuu0knBiX5gIXGoHgqarcX390bA@v3Kjl1XqH0T0cKkd9diHxm/pSqcIhVmr9/J7AuE1ijwZPjtjG2LC1Y8ZXuwSoVwSpeukgNxUm8BFLmQZAyD4CUjUASDXsd@ktyJlw8B9i8D8TFxTwMeryDgZSAAZK2beEkNo6Dr/XpfTBXQNlKkE2dzq3KggShnnwfjCezMOjc9V6wGic8ezrOun00XWf21LOllI3zygKMAqwS82ilES2S2jTeFfF8VYnGttplq2cFI4HE/TXNz4kQidGUuBcsAiXipxYFwML2n19Cv3SkWuPtgSMem4YBbVn6zOagISH4DBPfKhYkiAiy@DhUBMQJcXforPCj0ers6RJ4oPzSZOq9JXnKJ3wik055KBqXWDGO84dwoXDyeytfvi0ant2bf2Jh/kNnCDpOZyECFH@A8/h8UmpGpIeq6czQ@kF92cL@bL5cUb1t5uy3hzfyx3NFL0DRcWM6NGrbvBa9/12QRVn8GvgtNPm6zyNLkPxiIZK40K6LyS1mjwct05Ue0tR5Cg0ffIy0nHMlKZFgNQOGzOLkIboBio5HNkWWqAYjI3hsPMT1Go8bd2LjxjkykzPwbFy8dZ1iazJmQXO0A1O3xVFEosPsurh@EcRN4/HouLmLcrBsAwjtmZHpz/f8zo@2KULQIvkOspYX1z1yNd0Kz7FIhzkJtLiuqUzjY1ruu0TBCbQailWaVVR83sHF0DWumQt9CRRzdfEU2EO0p7sUImDiZVmKAe8M6Lt5tLScmONhQMqgah5AykXqVjDL/QB1a/pQdeu/ASVnK1SKuIX2IDrY0r1CbXaQTxfe@gdfDxYc3fLm/PAwduBJa@qPCgamW8zlcngIztztdrhAgavElpONx87inHh2eP2V@6aVxaTx@@wWXmeHOEBUjI1LE8gnuDQxhv4mcpwWzufYuCvng8dj8hN42ozMOK3AuP3NOTEfgUTimSX2HguI5XvP/HuoQXHkQwYBxbc3g9Sohl7JvpkckAc9OniiTmCSRsBo3Cx2LeDCR6V6Iz0SVzzSPB9ex6PehNsQ5edmv@@k2VvH7bdXZL47NJ7g8DCaIMejoCkhbzweXQ@RZuaV1Y9ckYFREDenb2p9p8vvWML7c/nsJ@1lcs0hrqQp2I@dmt2DyVCR6@9kYEwocgqLmWJyA7f3dGXoomRaQr8fLD@QDNB@UOyBPlQMotNsZOgDxV6q0AUYreMlmtw6GOdT9qDIaMyhxKKo/FwYTrP7YyNRF6OrfXAsW4GiY7CE2@Vo6zdVL5VkSfSAuPLFJN9BGuY4DIETHoH4sBS3ZTx06rf/4Ow2zhzg5kaa4w22xEbOG4uWw5@Mx5bFrkadDjQvPhNf9Y8a88GRqMzkyUoBSSMq1jW/HYM@oyQ7XpIfYIemNmdT24ghUi800iw5HnW2kwDhdyqj5LdA0fyAnmg28XUGmvXhmO5JCeUZTcOhAcW83MEETUwgSV8YlW@vlVqtxlaHqRSr1Z6BI5NhtWc1to8ez56xfXh/hu@PK4Viscwt5/bVG/B85nvesmcAg7ogvJNtH14hjK5awqEUVvFqtrKaLq82K7vVspet1541stkuuP7@D37y9//4T7M18fI9vjyjl/q7IJKmadlV42b18W0Z3@v7jeRqq746bCS7ZeSy/w8)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
158 [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
164 [CLIPS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/) (`-f2` flag)</sup>

### Explanation

CLIPS describes itself in it's documentation as an "expert system". CLIPS ignores nearly all lines that are a syntax error. This is because CLIPS is primarily a REPL and the batch mode (via the `-f` or `-f2` flags) just feeds the source file in as if were entered at the REPL.

With extraneous whitespace removed the CLIPS program is:

```
(printout t 164)
(exit)
```

The `t` indicates to print to the **t**erminal. The exit is necessary so that we are not dropped into a REPL session at the end of execution. This code is located between the Emoji-Gramming and the TinCan.

Just about anything that doesn't cause CLIPS to print is okay before the CLIPS code, including most valid CLIPS syntax.

Answer (score 6):

## 166. [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp/index.html.en), 8306 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] TaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((    (9999999999999999999- 9999999999999998975)/ 256*11+78));;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#( ((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=97
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \      @,,1'1'<>   @125iRE                               _
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001815

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8eAbIFiF4qOL3VVFLsmqmh4QxUokEkQWgUx0JkACxWLb7kk2t48z6W527mxuVrc9szqZ1kz3Ye0kmd3ZrpnMdF/P9kf0flyTaf7ByN0jIh94kKyZXTuBBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeEU0z6PzmNyn8sCOvO77oegM2sIMBa/nOle0b7NmYPTWdYLW0rCgYq@ZfDHu2OwjKSooVGXNcy2nBOxt4l7brfLR98C8x1ve9C9/ssUHHHDA7sMy@HTBvOOgPB8xrz062zNhez/vg5DBlz3EvINrA9vu@PaDwFcZeu12z12yZEyGrExn2fQgP2K7d/dT7NGCW1@uZbiuAmGuMvfT8wMb4lh0EHiZfZ2y0Z1sTQDcgquk73ovaqy8ngjYZ@xJQNPtde8TMZjDwTWvgeC7SpMBOXr0@OZpIUSyyN6f7@5O@JfZ1znPZ/tC6nAxaZq/9wOyaCfhUB0e@1xpaSJ9Bx4ZkSNO207UDxYKyb7O@qEkDHSzFfNts8WhK2/MZJmG9yy5zmNXvs2bX7BgW6zoQd7@wwWysAvYRwrudgI36PRY4PYASeD07jmPAXNtusaBvW07bsQgDZo8GthsApoHBHCjTtdPtspbdhQQRWlYWgLFhEPPiSBhKy1MYfKz@RCHCt0Ub4ri2JITdhxpCQnhYoUAVSY9r3@z3AUmg5AkgPnB6wH/OIB0w2wwc5HBIEthui2jYD3nfY6YbLyW7cqAGAN@hT7AD28eKMAgu69i@DSDNkPu0a98ZAAmQxDV2ZJs@O/VtW0@2g0SWkJmHOQywIAZV4dZWeu9wPw1VyVMYZn@gpPzl09/7SjGZUWWL5xX4VlW1ouy92mU3i2fo5mwP1d33NVNn1e9YkD87s@E7KjbzF/6tAlAVoEqX5b3@IG/m@oBgbgAI5k10oit3VTL63VjGbGuiLmIMxmO1oDbYgcveZKlk1tD3sWlHRDUvodBdz70AekJh/aGL9HDZWgGqwPKgZWaZfQVUg6ZAdeRdE4VPOw5UWoBVEmsEXEARQUFEAe8Jisp8A687pHiQMhggAwJVIClCPGizN6xtOl1MAuEIimPt28GwO8A0Q7eFNQ8CyG4ZTKJheS2M1POuIDsTgJIHtKderBUSUhAZKsKjomLQD//iz1oXFwCnZlme3xLs@oa1PItEqUnIgnxiyLCea3YJLYiXxdx5csjgyuw6LXOA2btjkQUhQblee8Nui3mQoX/tQNPqmFfQHNtt2xrYnMm59M2ynnnJZYfDORcK3jObULGUAeVNxc6xpztQS5atpIhncr3hoL3Bcv09lg7y77QnZe3JwpkNyOmGvrSYz19UgOGMJfKCt/RdnPOmlpCawcAMPKel9MeDjueWWM5iqlX1@rarpRMw0tm030zrBso0Ta84VctoO25LS28BL25Dxmm9YlWtulNuVCaSx7MEMNcIBpurrVm6qoDIoUZxle@Zjmv0x@xNTrhiYV5wjiTHYCPmjYSZ9LviHinqfZAvPWQQkENG0LXtvlYwijqKCYw3s9wYMKukEzBEgctOI5NOpTPxohMEKGmioNhYTx0PxVa338GOB4jiBn0Q3z7yrmUC9wQoxQegAmRZk/iaRD9IFpKJ13bat1kTBKnkI2qSvMlh@hwKSgEhakIyXrJF261YgwZhAG16EExJ5a53DRkTbtiHgQhxMXPzAqoIEvMC1XiBeI7kkyzapQuCBaE1bbaRazrQGLDZgWwXvB8rI0RfLvE4AI03lpgM6pljgGLxPjFqOMxpQ5vqgZjwx8yyUfaAELJ5x4KZDKkdBqD8oBpUyJVWV5NtbaqpDfx8LfdjENYf83e2KCx8LaEqQA/Utq9Z13QvhuYF6l8uJDEty@4PhMCCkgQDEEmT/Q555kQnagQdZfHpZN7UmYjuNZYHCntee6JLNFHKCA0s1wWhykyhQ7KW44N46o4nc4cIVxOZq@8xSgKB9@ocFKQmAExmj2xrOADpBox83XGsDvAuYudy@cg7o8nswSueO0j4XDvMGpEpbj8uKUY@9EI05oLIYY1Ow4FOFkFtJzyo8uMed0M2g94MwF6IInQIMV8jbxrAe/fA7HmuNwMoEDIEi1GSIbweQCM7QW0QOjCpflFjDVXEsIqgzkB6QMsH/usMBv2gDP2FM@gMmwZwSv7UHx8MDl1klvzAHzsDj7ubXa8J4jmA9pmXOeStYdMZTRSI/MI6/BAoV6CItQNWhR782yFwnZZuByA4yX8HI8eCVBLgBIL/qhCRIhlAKK0dkEjeB6FyMnYtTTWoKRnQ6NQsU7Hhqjo4MFVIlx2vh1KIvSUFATW@Zz5IrjZIKyH7SfSbM7u8sA8g/S6dNj54jqvdpBcWFtLl9DZI@IWFJ@DaQtcTdGXA9YRcOXJhPANdlCJLLgytUwr0a6Rv6xLySG9gtY2wd/ro9DWzXi4vN7JmvSieJXzqIOpAskHsHD4ATlqvVtGp6@r2NRTUaLaTpd9B6Xxi@U5fEOEr88rk74IKy0QGp9f3fFRkK9jZ3k2TXtWH3hCUV6uj@emzeuGscXZz1sqc3aazmFqvmNUmFAry03rGhe8NodvU6yvlXLGh6/Vl6Cyb1XQhvaRpG7kuZGTq@hcbesbk1NbSNkht7ewsDUQV9KlbHZ/gjbIlXQ9JBXhgBw26oZY2bjYg/6be0DNpSKunszDUqKbTQBkLiRBQoZEziUD7wIA7Jy8SQ8DeJYhHZgVd1ClyPlcr4DW/xD1b9AhVpzI7oJ7Vhf4SUIDushUOcVzPzblDUoRJS/XiGdFgDGOQH3YeKBidRBwE3HZGoOlDwx1LjQY7YFRqdmC453Vt4y3pGCoDzmfYXo2Zas0R7xcMK4gqERQYcPa7pgUtMwnuTGVnABAYNZ@fHaJXpgBP6jw0PLmvjNAzWKaL9Gs5pH4PnaCD5AUVCccEfhuoiro3dO42Ue2AWdBpXwCl7ZEz4Mo4MMIJJnluBpqO6l@Nq0@otWGXj0jJoTv1x54FAxcbun4M5aNAtudeOb7nIpGNPQANHFvBOpgAPou8wEa12kFpdz59ZwEHik15F2O0jUOdJK4VWCzvel3vwmNLEAFZ0zA4Yx@4FqAAStsAxokscD4SgWoXHoxgkjxoY38doJJXXFsO1WgTY@YpvvEBhAWbXegowpwynxz8eA9EfHG1UAD85VuBPmEhY1Amy4ieFosiiGYLTf@0M7QV2@p4TD2DDrK0zfIt@yqPzU2FnqgDml4OtCnbJ10iTCamppSBNwSlpGV3nZ4zOKA5mq6LPW/Uq8jQHWCvCMCRYw8UoS5HnTFO10SC0r3g8fdGKE8DxaYne3W4u3d@VDt9XlXzw8DPd50m1F/LPu@B3tS1A5WxFDu2IbVI8PGye@x5gypVCc4MTX9SGEnGf7F7/uLg2XHt@BueDaULnN6wa2JmPP4JvUs2iU0rtX2vF@qIgaDt4jJS005MD@LASYSuYOhQTA7G/NfQv4cTfoalXFgWy3n8NfQUEdcxIk4CGla/r1xkMhiTJgVDTxFzg0DixKDhN6XnJnqGU4IxNTwOblb4/EQC8k2xcIvAA3cY9GMluykWyf9q0G5jPxJ6l8j7MgdgQIEMvZfJm08pJrKSZJkKmhmZ19cpCK8XHgiqF05A87nxClTCHvFMUWW3nui91SikFA2zWe5q9vyAGgdEvAS1f@mhNhm5zmEsvIpQQhC9y@50yjbIdPpJRJ1CajqE83Cv2aafGRHKYsgJDRInQJEqX@H0GY56Pehh7WuKRsozAQNqOa6ZP6YHqtGz8EkOCBLINO32EDqfPGg36L4nWm5zg2K2m01nXlSgC6IunzOi@cPmLLKBMt@ZGjOyBOEHQ3/QtVvi@V9@vwUVMF09HXNMHW7oOAe6EW@059aWSIov9DO7ZinOh2HXMYkM5LoPpGXidJ3ZDR2zQaPsZLlcx/R72K@JygXmxB9om3fwGcfct7vDli2fszMhEidHpjy16/SoRPBExYwU7TnJJ8bVPD2pNl3PbBEUroA4dlTbvF7sEe@KY502iL8H4CmHvyyad4Zx3mDIf3Gq@b56dfr4nU2VcpLJCqtms2jnvcBsOvYdfOCbl8OWl@tfXlChEbW1edzOGxGO1nLtrnnJnefonE0AXkTfubiAUap4zot23QEFI@iDipK/pscdrCI7AEa9tHkXTL/Lf@dFkatvoWM@nZwu/XwOQxKLWNBqkLS4CJSLkcmZIGzXbI5xnNX5fM7CDKlnBcFTtTKZwjJ2Y@GkYbTc1O/PT499H6Xf3Jydmq9MEQDLa7dt@77WDD2S0zO7uVIr5pwrnOUsQOSaEZU035zVNQNgkoEgs30F1UI/dzEudjIWskvkuoNtI3Tk3PC86cUoTd@xvK4T9HlLEi/zpOTkxEwEBtcf6SdKim/T9G2Beo8deC50zW7onjXAKb45fPQAwcVn13D@MsYYhjePdpZ3jd@5qkPHu7L57@zO7ONMrB4ggnJd4gzHmpG8Zd3HrrhYRD@zqXg5E6uB1Z3pX2YvPc/v2G7ASkZBTkfgDL3Z7fLpvtODw/k8HThdL4CRAf7eRQsYAQQB/53NzXGyOaabo0mXuHt2MoFUnxlijDqnMs3uhddd27jIm/Azt8aHfhslu3g@VKKFEqlYvFcihYqP5xbFc64ov4T/@5iBJnZ8nMGNOe/oR2eJLzHzN7@AMDzAZZnZhdsvbFBKI8@HafMqwLc61@ZYPn@L3mIedWVv0R@T2gx6HSbY3ADHwOeq9G@T28rdubUeJpOmwK7fV4hY5V52bZDQ9DtVpaxUKH5mimKh8HAJ1e4O7aE9U2IcNj/YaP1yh6x4OFIFUYxFMWWRB@LhhEUY66MYFD4Ia@y/8e1OAWN2HWjk92ovM@VdH3TtPo6jj8BxhI7phBfusJ@o3Bjtjofu8d2U6/Rly/ZaCSQx5HMl0sb9OlJCHQ9s@s5T3fd6Hgx9vR7oDO4D6l8ApTkg/psATD4R5A8Ozpf5d8Its3CpB/RV0D@gVp3LIIeTbg8TPKV5Y3aKvLkJozLXHozxdx61ZwnSpud1P6d2QJ62HFTLQNlEm677amlK1xGrfiyanQhwpqPZnjcvwfsaMYAE6uFgeW5FH0GRBtQ5PKSWpyb57ui1YlN@940jocemyZ/At6R7Hr7H2LiLxoaxfifCXB31mnbX5I/R2spd8DaN5YeoRH2p59KsL84U87nhaKUiNSGC@mMgltPKBVbH7tn0eoeSb7Y@DAP5mBtp5OF3RrCRp2nROen6DrR5F38T89AxrWjguXaQH5j@hY3Dky4uDwjfeXJWzrbOJO5Bz7yw9@9lrmj2AU1CaPkt5pw9D1Hmq7QWJLtHkvCRn@de2uNAPmfrx2ML6nPYuxParHZu4STnvQ3byM@cZL5H7XM7Xsft2B2fGkf4Nq95AEcOuOnrXYUA/DtmcIk2MCSTomFdJ4hTt@t1uw@hLspELiE9b/b86x4an7Yg6WfBHZtNCBCPe6fqoOsmIlEfPq/tdOwh9FCBN/D6do7e5kXt4qQO/509pXxwmA7YW8f2W3z9D2f4zIHT7Nrs2gEUPgTxdbTZE0bNrmeimdUdSjxQRj4fMgVlef59vcKF6Q36fXqc97vDgH5oJjfXnj1FWWb7hOhDeMEZ8JVXzrH2hde0Os59lde0zYHrXOZF6xevs7k8KYup4A7L7aK30XWAVP7YQB6oxsNP8HEwu907L4Th@p36yM7Q98f3y4bkqmI4q8rXAtAxb/5FrBbNCKaeH80L5DL6HQsSYnFpLkORLo16c84ugHJSnDsblDCFECToLi8P7qGS5VmX96oTc@cnxUIkkspyYsul4D85iXE3Gs@FeIPBofZ8eBHo98Ufo6q16/S4ibzZjYyA7klZu@CcgwtJQde7jk00g0gwXfGYyXmlF/e3J1oNWb1zYaTMii/Oa4cH9wOzuk4/4L8s1y7NVCGmFxtn5fgNVuEd@fHFyGMyJw8NDoOssIMHP8cXVs9BuLUgRSYJZH4ozdFYCo0ih8gVA883GMXTNDOT0XWFJ8L5tQsXoslYZNyNBp/cbjxgXScYUFynzep1tngzKhfKxVtWZWpZZY0Gh0qmh3ujPlllH/Ok9UWzUV1M53LpxfSZW2aFNEW1u4E9O6qZiNd26MHxjIrOXJMbnKBblrTCDVmDDhmLgwRtgSR@Dfo7tUbP5@aY3Ob3FBfq/vNftoQNPWhrAes5UG1ACNz34fXsjnf9hOcrcq/1@yba4COM6w6Kecw9t1NjwTWKbG46712z1/unG8IQV@xOgZcjlC0xLHil4tABrXAGvNI4Ni3P5mwhMg5TyUJZXnfYc6GPbA06gcFOHDKwGfqRYQG4MJo78FFRaGXZAWvZuBxCdlOkG3c975IsGBGT//yX3PyYrKeEVYvMnrYfxHJEI6ki2fxaljcErCWQj7bviSgaEhmYf4gjT2Bqm/vraFNEdtHAiTlpFYzZcMvgndoJy@2xNG6fQVvDitPWFmvHX76pFxrV71gvb/@X38/rN4Ju6he59bVAzTIZpXKLfBUPXoXgKDTN1MWRKoqFGzVoX0LIVGIHl4Zuqi5p5dujPR7Ed/Y1WfmSbYqLbRs3T4DEC0A7G@gEmjea6qI25GOc3MmAreIeIxg2mODiu0LIZgotVjHJ4oh9Yh3klZyFdjzwxgnSRSPpXvWZXOZejhsj5Hft5pBW4K5KRmm5SsVZPK9ubZPLt1seblqovzsblQq5s9H6XiMfSOKcnY2@KJR@BNTzQP1afJzHBrT3avdm0dgufPoUmGOmqrfpCrexgFa@eHN0cLR3clo7fX0C1LzlhU3te37PjCQF8gKZJXW8Lu0GAbL4jh3cLz1CCRK@QXRNY4sm28KNZ7quxG1yKKogtZpTF7kzjALjkHjqe5LPSh/YsfDpCEIytR0mpCg7IkYSPJMO4hI0K3kL6wWbO2iLIUXQgmWGKCQaqawKVMoBlR5IIzZdSl6DT8gDqvF@Qt0NYxYIoFUUYzoCEinMC8vLw3nhZhb@9h@gxH3o137XEhOMO0uMMe4qMUSMklGK/drBi9fHe8lEwE7R1j8Y6/m4C7RNbYtvIuLc5Yn9KlIy0TApEHbpoWwN2JUT0DAK@a2NPUMXhAs2R1qID1C6cCtWVusGIMlbLRBNzfEAJRuIdINMq7h9Vc5lagqIZYQdbZapCsYNqtP7FkByXVsgxd7zxIsUjyAHyoyNVmd2/od/8Wd8c9XZANx/JNyjwjN4@xPx1gb3P5chxSK8/cvwrQRvP@Vv7/JIyumdJLw0IRGRgG8OjlhAIz0kUc8cxUqPfRv2nY4LYw2nB7S@ItJhdF6siDIRHK3@BigP1QVkRyGNcpnys/2GhvsAyvk8qiI4PWeQ@Y894uM82hbw7RC3xUFXkl9bXVspwkDHzl1JgGTae4H2JhygrpeBK5Urp19937TY1tYWUwPL7NrVtQoneX7RfLesvg8RXYS4Ctda6gzSQJIoBYRti2Taopkp6pgUG2e6mGaNCigkvAahT9PIAVF09HaldSh0mp4gFbCHa48GJPjHUhsDVcgl40Sbb46UgHIAiMPGzVuTXB5ZkKDBXYzvjXg1qG8x2glGK6uzmKz@jp0NztyG2MTHgGF@OYPlXHD/8YydfSH31Ka3lGmTG8KwNOzpieuhpdE@YMu0Ur60nC@u6bE2pQpQgC@2oE8AEtoMtEHLdj54/aC2s3fw1eHRydSWKIqZnoyWZuntrcxZzsjWG6EjPcH1kqjP9vMnL5/tS1LGsYom6jFGNFs/ieas3CYxnZP7W266M503BUxlVCw8FDCNNnP7tKA1DT0Kzcci7nDTgqlcNf3mtt7Y2j5zU1PZf5q1XTRlLCFzgessoM2iaTZD5hxIg6RTPBcgMKT9akmNNkOHFqv8PfKev6kpPGUg2tkkTZ8UMtoObbYVY45RFJTdyPOsaFsPR0ziC7JGolpEVKMMLWVqsSWODRNlmT4QQdgmh0Q65ANZ2rVpujCG8R2Lxw5IQPPhLm0xhAHPwSAaI8G4C2cYaCg4pmEPiIpwjqPl0ADc9KVpcRhyYvec3KnEBwVHtFNJbNHpQNm6TrNiVusjFtr93rVhxwj6XWeg4e6hkYHDSSiNpmMBilu4/Wakb202xE4nJjckZWhP09EQ6HXk9Vk0hN@1pesYRnFsdwjAgQ1s9tWwB/Ha9Di2sZew2SsvB4mBjmmJRB138YgyGL3WKuRudOxRy7mAnkbTsyCSvigWo91QJm7ncdMghzmpvkQLlDhhPmsHV4xiZt00HLdljzTceFBuIHXAP3399iqtq1M8QNvIxK6q1uR@MikszIFotdFerAmBsLkZCoJk29ncNDqBgnbZMAKBHE8G/gtwQh@qtXtmn2lD2pAXMIPRq3amudlg4Osst4392TVzWSZDYxd4UIDBKGWbXE4Xp3k13Meu5atQz@gbuC18fHT6rF40jAa4KROdLeLsww6oGzhu1xVQTSFJmcBCBwx/ZcToGkZpiBF/LlK2Cm2pgVgzg6khX3SoAQItqNRs@3G0gyPWAjlVNzfLojaS4nCTAVtszZAYAHaGmJO6KdBXWNYC1VCIQawdGJQ6IFCefm27LrRXDXimB62TmUNgMl/PygNZstH@fMohxVF8Lkx1AdHkvv299E3XA31mMV@hEXDlFvr992fY8bdF1z/O/7d5I1@50Ra71XEelDF9W1vsVIuZ5aVMZtFd0hZdVEceP8aB8@0iaDvnhmqoI4iUW@zqFeBn0I6qi25l0dzSFlvV0hKlgNdMRr@BBN8FeeNm0bzNLz4GbSILPj5vndpiQFvpCoZRvAX8sIUs5rPAMze4pYyOWcHsF51MBnEwFs8Rge/yZycZ6lfOTvI0Rq8IJTd/0ZNiJKmrhDUxdTwMJ6DwLocSfRUluliOPZeR47v2Z4TdqV1/jcYrjCba7SCI81cy5OGCRQg0FE5CyGh8LyMQcKQBEfE1a@o6CJPf/CZVXINR35O1Zc3LPFktVDLp1WIlnWKpp2p@SfXVm7Pd3BWzc@l621w1vm0cXR4d/Ug/09gmS6d2DtXiivqObZaW8koqv1T4tJ7Pv3//HtRhVt82to2GXs@lG3WND@jW2fb6@lJ2bWMp@zR9Ho0g15mulUo6VNoZW2Vn66a5lFkpPXUrELKJn2VWBCf@bsC3yFZX2R5@/vb/@Nuf/@3P6O/n9P1rx3H6QasFX6/DLtlH@Fy2Gf6T@2Mr5jbR3Wx/1GCcAepnlZpG8SidXl1On7zDTbNPFuCP/uETvuLvAvkIb4oy/VlQUttW6mOqWCymxvR3ju7iKDZ4ztHLaN4nXyyWzvBQgOW1hacMqGqDEMVPufw0hJFX1zdUzyOPDuSwyrwUax3Gchnl8KOk5PETubrZbrBTE//YaRP/jgf4l3tziX/HFv49u8S/l038e/ER/04t/CPMNqpZBoh9V61yhJhAbPIz29swzqULobzfel/93T7scz4jJQUDutT2diOTu72tG@8ylYr4B1FYCd/ww12Ab@M2l9t6t53J1Anv@rYowFausc1LQ7/G@bstAJvZqm9tGefb26PtXOPddh1LeYM/o1v8LanQus6W0FkdbR1ziLsSJLI8wz/6vOCZ1I9ewADmNFvayqVK@7WdbOnk9bNUEd5Wo1cMXMbX473a7uFriH30Yq92svflwZu910fgHzTOt58@zRjADk8B3@1GHVD6IrOdqQ4Gg/Mfny8Z2Pdt8i5wM8Rh4nM@w8VfldTu9uh1PrcFSL8438QCHlNuOSBG4xPjYJVUPVXXMk8yTwrdwlWheFm8fOkdRv@HhyMIcEaFD55f6BQ6xRY0G1awXxfGhfGo0PMOiy1w2vBX6IHTKbRHK4drh09HhYuCW3CLxQS4@f@9Q@/loQcAPUg2GBUGCLvQhufF4eFLANaG7D/An1MoFEaA56hwBf@FbpE@784LUGgdd47CW6FwdqbUmfreBhFoFNNGIW2spdNOY3Wt/@3NbWnt2zppbKubjTpuEm6oLJs@P6unG5VUPjg7y3NprZZW1ArtIr69PT/frZ3Wzs/zONE12lrMPM3knsKnup3ZEo8nqdZ25clZOYfsJxkxld96cra9nEP3WgaoXwK/rXzmMz8RSHgunClp7frt27f4fXt9dc1d5OB@Z2/DUPx5mwcv7kIv@GDU/Kz0ScdomuM0rb7auLmFTussXUmLbk1jtCFfLZ6NSm1WUnHooG3qoDkUl1E/XVtl@vb22ip4rG3oOa2AQwue5Ezt9/tnqkGTKQaZYlarNd83xziA0lYAiLa5Wq2eqaZ/fqbWSw1Mu5rbXGOen9tc1lVdf1fc2oI8MIuSDt5qeqR6fprd3Mb/tJvbLY0@Ov7pOnrqwDX03NY1iKCvwtvoRmNb2paGfuCF6W5ut9FJ8W7AVdf0hn57y/3gV9O3ONRtHQjHQGv4R/qH3uT/P/8vX7MAlI/bFKrDLltZ1bXm2NZX1rSNzKb4qy4AYTV1Ob2Mek7aTNfrT5eWl9ZX6k8aS8YSfrWts@3GjD5XB@0HGrJsetViCisWJZlROVaLJTWN7lSqYokjCLreBVverGA3jQlV@KBLSTOo0O2tkIWj/kffxvpnVKNMbzD99gbYmgeCyqyJVaezs1GhIBPprNKsLt6kzNtKCnNht6pMIloI5aGlK7Q0qd6oi6ZfLzbUW3XxpnmL44ulok6q5epKpbK0wt2LlI5pm9OfHJvw2NhcX9XzrLS6tlQsZtY3dB3gFJd0PlMPymMldG9UKnZgWhUUY5UUoKVpaagJPXWmVJv2BSAD5OrHW3hmdXV1IV@Cx@iLtb3SaEl8tpdmfDZKG5mlzNP60uYmVmiDPD8tKBVcNeRLlGpO5WKCbWwSGilc38DPlr14BHqJ@FvaXeKuIn73FgKlz1wYta4XWMvr4uY6r91eAM@OGbCmbcPwzO525XkXMILstq6dlr2g1HujdoM2MFdz9eLaaiMHTPJh1GbEGEpgw6d3ZNpD274eDq/t8LPjBOaHD2afPqP2D7/8yQ@//O9/@NVPf/jVT3741c9//f3PfwLfv4TvT/nzp/9@cxV/f/39v/xffvjzX4HnX8P3P8H3P/76@3/z@/xL738D3/8r5vc34huLx78KwPqTX3//s7/49ff//Bfw/bfi@4vJ7w//@j/w//9b/KHzVz/867/BH/Hyk59Ccf/@r36J/z/7q7//T7/E///1f/77v/pXf/8n/44cf8Yd/8@//ff89@/@4Cd/90//9O/@4Ps5vz@58/f7B/h//4/g83A8HwLnIeX6XJ/vfyt8fhdqRLkADwCn/fEP/@YPgVf/NX/7Z/AG/2HQH4UviRD@8kfRC0D4n2Yk@uNff/@nfxG@/WEyYiIMgPwRhP15IuyPfvjl7//wF//dD7/8sx9@@SfYSnMrm9laNle8e/SQgoirD4iHEdceEg8i8igLbEEp0RN/hCdbINdoSVldxkFWjn8y3PPTIqqe7OyTsgrvmU95PMiE5T@J0DPcBVOE0OUVCi2AFl3A0FV8laExVHBF@snThHLPEVn69JRBZEgci0wRn3BEhX/mU0KoY0oKXwgRh2@U2UKYfmEGYZ6wpxAMPSh1olv4iy/g8wxGfGLgV93eYFUlyzaqbJs9w4hVeKdwdNI79Ld4hm9V2WXPcKiK3rtAIT72hgHhexxcZyj6No/KthUI/w48nnEwBA1BfaeAV4b77MLzOxF/pBA8/BcaLLrxKwPgJ8O4H7xir0NwxI/CY/BgJh9xauIwG@NhuhH@swiQgJNRgBCZbHxkFmaRibyU8DUzlUuIz0RYJgpjovNMgMqwKYB3BSa8lcmEbCYUgcHc0IliytAZOcrQ1HSSMChOoEwmSTBMmSxURsmg7duSyHQps0SmLkuf@xE4UQYzyXHHJ07vpajkcbgR9hFUwpcnyFDcKG@CqHGditYKWHFtJQSsKxoddwXaKdptKN945XL1u@LKugJPeh/iQVriSCdgVTwl2diCD8bevslhm1a2T/ZOIez0kBVLBYPVC42blfXSyurKaml5bW11vVRcWdtcWVvdWC4UC2uF1VKpuLmygurorbL9IzYy2NHR7@VuAdAol8uXECKrFlfXK@MqpCQvZZsUM64Qjm9yoAsiBmeki96goQHOy9zQdNwj@DDlkcIegRd8crcKzrcysc51cFgRqyFoExeq33xpRC2ubqqkredygXJmuy0OXFlnr4/g5/jgy@ensefpXm3nubLGnh2@2p14rIpIq@zF3v5p@LrOQ2XS1RDEN3svXky@igdqxQtsdT2bNQwDfvCZpQ89jcV3MkrRmN9LqWuF0rpazJ6PbVCNb3K52wunaRfXYEy0oj5OgUaOh3qd8GPLBjBcHrWJ6Jvryks0ZdgschtUJ0BjOwBx7ZKtYxNPQh3253vCA73Q6TsXHWDCay@MEATB9XU4BfFWzjeE8w5vWdM08fu5H8jBjn8Gd3sMeB7kNxXSnY6uPIdBRg9P/MLNHAOcQHfarKAYyKGl0ubG6sbmcmkju7G5sbIKw4nVbLGULa5vrG8WssVCcaO4trG6WcxurGwur0BjgNBVIHQKOM5p5/PQgouqSk/HtfAomS08k8czOttKqmW30SqTjbSWzlKt0GO4wdTljbMCg4SqgvZRS6OqWlpBy7HlIiuqimoyi6X293cK@/uq@gxfcPJrp6CqLXxZ3SgU1p@pqk0hO9BgS5Cog297azhLpqoOvuzU9vcRwgd8KW0gDFW95CH8pStf1iGaiy/LywiAqeq3IbgCAPc4RhuUasBfCoVnO6o65OhtwB/Eq/G3FUJ2D18wABPt85AdCFPVL2UiUKNU9ZjHE1k9l@Wt1VT1gL/UagjiKyr8Ki/U1/hSow8k8uENOFdVL8Bx4cMAUlWb4ET@VVULXNbYBL8euHD7mjswVXXMy4ElUdURxTatS1U9l/6QD@Dz/LnZGbTsC/4Z@/xpQdABBDmj4d5@88svmxcXTX9c2/vymIK@@uq5@WE89JsXTZGweQ4fD1NB0GVvPPmxMej83OzODvoagtyJoPPxuU0YnpvfAmbic4EZ9c6/wqCvIGjWkocACJ8eRG7i51kPns/MJg@SHwqi56jZVCvIsth02hoxrpmlBx0wp98wXLkONPMJyaoyyimvrRWyww09t/pkuKGuravlJXiqT9RlcELTYIV0gTE1faaqen2z8URdX1XL6SdPcunHxSdMXd9Uy@r6Osh6vXKLYk7Tb9raKDuqFsAjn9/CBo1NEJ5h7yO6iNKGCsITvGUE3vLDtgt9B8hpBt9cTsHwflVgrDINz7lEC3BaztTS6fVSOq2nK5B2QQVcBCpkJI5FlhirIDMA480SJPftwdB3WaFyO5Wzf1kOBqaP69mUQ5mpa9ChgTceHjr9eQrDm2x5qbm6tf1Ppj7/zT@Z9Zntix@Fd89rRSV1q7Tw6JiVTSV1o9ze3G5tyxy/ZuOxmZFDCPaYsYvMorKYxoKnl5M6c61auziuyVmy2g6M3Ja9FS@1uLiopLZOt9Vl9dA4D@fFt/O01HKG6zC4ZmGcnW8tZH6rSfOcsf1UrjIB6nnFt9G4u4V3M/DJ641VrIgLFqQyv@UHMlGqAFOp4IyjmsLWY3W9IS4HsjNeoK3vUjS5zY5u2kOXrHvKL1F70cwy76nrDWDh71453ZuN5dw2LUprwGG3t8QV1iGtGCop1xNOICTogQN7NNBA2VklZQfqq3@y@W793ca7l68PXx/uPy2UN8obRPUzySjZYrqYpnp8Cn2Vc7x3jy57DkroJ2@1@J37VSVV7qeXV9LLYeBZNcXJCG5sG1q9Xmyw@nKjUQd@bDAdXqvV0pPi6kZmpVxcZ3pqu7RuBOY41RA7Y7SVdR1eaL6yVEy9TX6uEy9XtDSnpDZevv9EM4j8ggGnRK58nrHF261b@N@@rW9t3W6hjSk88J//3N7ycPrHAsgXekSfRLwoThT@27GjcZ5qfJfb4v9b@LNzyImgrq2qeup9dRuY5N35u/OUktpkaonqNZPnc5J9xrjSsuTSnx0s4d@7yGMJtLCl8M3eWgrY6jYM68Evn8@f6b9XAo1mc3NtYy2l/AbIdYeVH4SGZi9t2/aDYW@W3UvNd16aaBPkhrYv4Hg5/IgnyD6Vd0hI5Yeh9oOGXaj@xP2ERhTzoqtXkn7jII@7ENBXUdDl0P1ArE2ch8sAA7ImZ0u4nRU3W@nKjfIIYA2tAW1ggJ@KojxCS3p81WS8LHscDHScqSjoyqNHQjAHAyMYnCNwTCQ8c8WKcqsgecxWK2B0hjOuXvEdWibapXt9fu5Dd8x4ooDaBtfkaHMV5htDeIm1ORZQmiVGORLmWDie/SMerTlsIyr7By/2IA0MfdpkgSJSq34TTzin4i20dRb2L0ADPOa3KihF0TEigANP3lHrPdwGZmkUM8OKGN4mSxaIlWXFLGGSZW2RsI6vDUiO4Nsg7wIAzHPXeAnY0rnIVpRB4EOFABJi6aibRIfpX1hZUXt4JmK9obMbudlEw1C2xUrRbhgBCyqD305ECa1eS5zWXI3ITNCKjSxUbYVvWtDCeMInItStsjTI9iq8qvoV5WvNAn3C87XKd73Hj613/XqvUdF71QE@M5kedN2XmsOjLA2qvSqwR7/uNCqDeibjNKo9/WsN3/FQdOznhVYU6KJsUHK3CrigZVCgZz/W3dx3biO7X3czgPIwu/Tj6sesWS2gPpN1qsVsN/tttSjKAXkOqh8zbsXcgi9acyU2hIC2kjErCS9Mcql1qx/rZgMVpC4kzGT2oTCAZ1DvZjINHTLvQuB0wkr38WMz090eVbq5nI6x3i0/2a8PwNHIVPG9rJlboycf60NIX9bgWYVsujogD@kErW9D3AG/CtCY12mEOseR9LcRoNerVpd@/GTpx0vVhYWP9VGu18hy8pcLETcg8iNEvhLbcKMt/VhnEyShBT1N/cIpf2GAcFSzTiYDRM72Yyk5hks/hpB@JiOxvkV5SXemSEtB5DCxSYQfkEynrZLhL51SHdBh74MWbpeDtLXAchwRne9z7DswkjZxS3OWTkI3KQaGiUucMPBs9OSJIrMW@xIgZxQuTZuZOCKnKzx8XFmkC8H47u375OssMSxlbjgSpVO5Ycy7vBZrriSaqMEFvlXHKCgGbgq3FS6x@G4UEDYkPSAOSQ@Ml0MpgkQSckLErIpAqC1ZQZAK5USbnzxAe6xRPqHOHbZ8ECEcDWjMM9Bwsh@qJJuAnxxwMWeL8gMHNBXlERQCccAyOA22DYKMPX7MxOtWlRVL69gXYDSM9yFTxEhTmELmD8AUYCCWH4BHUR5SJoDbIwzB3VaJjFZ@t4zEZkkNEmQ@ZPmeSYP2TGpDN@BbhZFuOkcD6@LRow@Z6opACP5pyALpIez2NynR3ZfZzuHLo9ene8cvayfwC0O4jfhlB/JCoalrRPp4PUjTcWnHkGUeF@1vvrIY00AhHuDRqXhfWIt99foFK5Ve7Wbx4DMgfYrPVkKHWg4h2QEdLB0Ynn@Rv3YunXzydkK82ok2J9FdiDl5KwKiQ51zN9rAHO1fDnA6DDpzcVpT4gKCnh0E4naUnLxxjs7KoK3cPdyRDK1Q3KZCdt/SdJUMpXEFO0vm975z4dA1Yh0OIJGezpUf8OTUPhS8BaVlDkzkaGVzo1Aos0IWHUXpKEnHsnSsSMeqdKxJx7p0bEjHpnAUJeQihwyD4uXltci5Hjk3Iudm6FwpRM4Iwkopci5HzpXIuRo5o9xWwtzWNgguS0lqUtO1fQwrrmzIMDyAAEZF6LkKYIqTniuAaGkqJiRfmfKE/DaSnuubBZHRQf4QI5VKa9E7SB8Zt6pxrLIcjyzPmb8JT@irFD4AJIbd832QSnsjvPYJmE4vM9yQqSggdpnVtU1QBuwBaCnVfeB/Wy/zgwr8cTnalIkQqsXwHZLjrQOQpkg3mHH2mRFcmhXMoZVmQuMnPbCQMLEdrQJJjmU50dNyiCsJvzjUBRSwSNE5MUo8BtZBcguszPPUH87McvnuLBMAZ2Y5hRSHuzorFdJGI@BVmZT6f4JWlflxPcWm2gY1QNxXSTwwUaF4YkX1plhWf/39L/439uvvf/Yr9sOf/@r//Y//I7r/A/7876CzsFIY4ac/Y7TWDj//itHKOq3yR4ko/nJZ/eEXv4TX/@HfsR9@8jMe9Kd/oWZXQkAQgl5Ryp//M/z5Q/z5P9Xsahjx53/MI2ISNXurJFQrDWL99K8Zg9wQSgjsF3/JmJoBBUMTnFfnbbwR29/OAYRkqJOrMRnOf/G2H6BxQc@oAFe8FaO3DFaAHgPum3gBY9T2QJ3hq0gopS3T6uAeZuHlBaj/WKjCeIFxAfx23QKlR0x0pKH0f8DKLJ3BODoac7dwjEMyXJRflFuNQjFuRs0DdnhjiABFdyGFmMDwVgH@ppHAODBw2EIj0iLnEUHfV3jBq@xAVMlZdDWMIvKSqXEmRlyTR3cFyaEuMi12Q/ygC7oiRxGbbIuxDBPiZqLaIJdJHxgyRlvf40nJw@71oUogWUhvJCy@EBWyk@CimhPNZu9wf6LB4KcJKuZlXCKFGVWZqt4TFykt4uuocS0n43N8RYR6obzcSGyknxVZ/dGPfqQqMb8C8pDf0ghCrFBcZIRBxWRQKRZUigUBzhwmyZrVUmkCB@o4UC4mD43gyWIiKpksYi5sObIeEA0YC/Kp0my7Oww61WnQJJGTwm4aeAxksVEV7eTMJZmzzVR9KgHATKapTtblbNCFqTjTFTU7JVI74ZOorfmQEmlijYKop0xSKay54uasmktmeAfoYiPzwIxKhd8xo9wDM1pbvT@jyWrFtAnw8@l7v9iRYiKU8BEw3vBTiQ4Ku8ZfAOtF4ggx9smp6TDkqYkhT/PaY9qM@xDBPy9POk1cgujHzj/FQcwrb2Dz6YGnfQ@GHB5qwbFblGddny4uLb5wPd8O4gdkOHwLsZvGI1os78KFXi2LJ6464oZPXJ/nh3El@5WwZxNa6A6/mBlBc0Kh5nl@7rjO4PwclM9uW48IiK@Ghfs60wre6AyuWHotVG0P@5qHJ0cP9Pthkr7Lk5061qV22BeBacikxmBAZ9ldGHyxDt71FnicJFhEfvsbaKTNgUbHu3W8nndhux6eToOpJ8AfRLARIbPfJ1yyzMwyK4aRGERrVtbURdKvPzsp@7qEtxXK9KUkgAQxssyfpDFS1p@R3fnc7Hgymd/J5@N7Esf35G58244fDCZxJk@c7cHn52W9rEUQIGKExvL9aGTFgVRT6CRQCb3xnlGe4MEotuzAgu4PMa1B1JqIbrSBP7LhW0A7OAXib@bR/@4KlMn3Hlp9pMyejEHe9OhaQBqiBXQcn2vZGkQ/0PXIdiyWXcjauw/MSwx0aISXZSoJLhe3B0PD7PdtF2@m4x8J@B6eR8OhKb4na6IqD5yBk3@VZZel@VW0e96yu@bYbmkiZjYGV5b42DZbJK8eVnAUdCT0PH65rFbIFhOqGB3jQJHKc1jGzF7p@ny24lGckHtoMY4wPJhPP5q4mxTNOAla5Wsgng8SNEUnvdH5ev1xf8yPfunyS@2FHOX9D6/JV3gizr0EATrwyxeL2Shb/S7xeayFRXpAjxDGNZJFpg3UstvyQBufqsPPI9H9JaVZhjBRVdZyQjuZV@POXTUe4wrJk1wreRhL3sd0D@a5GKtxYJEI2/m8LmQK8o7Z7VqWFofIfe6sMc@dkgnohzXmuXN6lfMZAjVMSZJugDddVbl@oSsOOA/geQXPN/BEgDAGPecMJcuGeq2c8qKQntmPaS3Cp26hLhqjoh5fR4zFUqQbJ3JvwzytuXlaU3laiTzDFpDMMhZJsRJZilrA6rmrCrp2ezBHOmMQjtzhcZfYho/rmT6uvd6knXTZybL0VboMAjltp8t7GgjldCtd3iVHkC6fkOMyXf4aHFHbSn9Kl2WzwAg@vJLjKfoLEY7vVrq8o@m3Ct5uH8h8jXQ5rFOI84S/EkVu@fRqU6z6e@Gsqo03B6NSmWXIMQE8PCxWvZGlbwH@Kao4PhUCF6qstESRcQCS6DRiPQbPB7oNA@9@9rVZ3UdZTk2J@Y1oDgXCM9XYpApyyZDkUTqVTgojjhiG0uQjPAFBlJvl2Rix4tTI7D50RO4O3tkMxE7mT9QzSB9oaRReh8jxSZxulF7WVxIEr8CH4YmJ5@E5hY7MjjBCYwB9BlpI1PfpOwqFdT1xFCev/XgNTc8RYCXmZBReSwQ2JtNBh0PdlDLre/0kk1AorvY58TT4EY0SuXciGUkF0TLnBJO3KBkKhnjj1@8qTiwdopYQQRhYLzR4Kwv7BZLFGBTJupimyhsfoBCTOS06G8tGtt0VTorHxU2W@op53ZBMy7MkyZUUk5DYwJ3nQ3PAc4/WZXA/@ucNX2VKUMEBRwQQSxnmwuWr9xn6u8f1d6lQSyJMZDBLsZ7dlU6r13f2shOYd6NspysQA7NsV5@pHIU5RCSH0UFMM7@L16ZUfLwUlSv5PNMQ@oS2L8kWjgnuodvk2ILDQi3Bv0p6XuLE7GVpPqGmNZLulSGVFgNzEnB4wUNMo6LdjSsv@KwqxhDso@Hx2RXsJys4XnkIjwrgT5Cct3J/6JJ5VdS26YSjaOWCrzp4aCUWHiwb8wRxT/ZroYkWeByeH@8evnrxDXS66@vr@vRSBLZaSBv148qdywThsKWUxbMB8Thjsp3oeP5g4cxVp03KyAOUAZPWbTj7iTauC1kWk@cTbRfS8bgxigpYl1EzMBNSCVUdE7tsR9CV38SjLZkCiFRvgd5ZGq3hqhFyBy7onJ9T93V@jsY55@eiF8OqCZeRfpMSd/KWInsNJZW0ZiKNK5g6gAsnAIY92kkkJ@DE0VrcDiUFcA4GMnWYaugOHGnsgPNDtDtNruVry0WcnThohz6EBxplaKUVHMKWVvEgD54KY@PEJ5lWinwWuKKDJ8wHfc@lM4Lp3EVS2/G8@0BOvRLaQ/faJDMQngudPxLDiBtkyXUxz@WHvwc8Le6boylkSZsssy8MWvEpbcKQ49Lp86NjQ9OPQKdEhDDZaAGNm127ByidAO/OmE1@6UCtdPadiwtgpLy4XoobuJyakDTntXM78ki0FHtjdp2WPJxb2ITRwfhiHhjIqSXOtAtYaQ20qc0sUDb6AmHRTIbhuXUFMtKiWPBdh8c6d25kY2kXtLGefBblR0d4C9o51izfe@z4eJXUlenG6EyfT/GpabFoSXIgtnIpT1FTxHGaVVqnNNBGra@pKVUer4ZObjZhdi152puG5wyWlUcuCR60AGMWt60BBddFpY2W1/TQJNVlX7DlkkJXAng0ucyzBRh8ZS8BHcIgKSLLrfuEgFG/aKlf4GKi8iiFspDzGqaXrIxuOqY74mW2IMDxBRVsyrwJyJfV2MsyDDUezch4QVMzACWj6moCEsQXqx@PuOSdTgpCEcTD55pi277vUjTlCkQJo3tBhRlx5Q7DXrLsRfPBhF0vDqbihpptYb/GL9PJqq/RAqvMM6G@w8DTM1F0VyZld64ozTXpgXbSbIn2iLYTHY3qY@IQjQXHvQsB6lGIQ1HOkPnXF0EZvoBDVoIEMpHFgka00e/FjSiCdtR4UkChUYl1KVoxjg0i2A5AoLSBnln1C7RafQwJqYuF/k6fpTYVKon0gFzQd8mSW80ZKiUVVscIKQmC1yb6h7avChm8S8F1x3ngZr64UVjbJPtp5mYH2V59s5FdsqoqsweO6faCoX/durzwOlegLLD@h@bIGn/8lrHVFYa7SkqP@W7o4lo1Txue1@nEgE06fmdRHkdAe@rPVMZolyyefpBmLNyKVFnAbdDwyeJPWa1McSlb6kku5EbUvfpao@pWC5Ve3W1U3ExGH2Sqg0wxo6HH46JeAUnLp13qgwZZReaX2EtpuoinZeLcqtdmR55rdbx0wOhGvviaHu0vkw2oZ/bj7ekKRh2eH/dpIz@ZvURDnPbCXticSOl4Mt5g3LdRNIZWn128zhR/Hg3XVirT4VjCR4/QRLkidNN4AW6U/rDZdSyQQURPVDHQXLFcFkb3FkO@BQGFfg735LhAD6RhcEWGWl5/LBI7PMq5LMtWDOS2hn2Xnn1ITBmrCTx5jmeb@xCNR@HkTURnAJq6Hp1jhe4Xthv2M7hPQq@gFTlbkGFyRwXGR76hfQ3noP7RLgh4bDERlWyMmS4sesm37qBRAalq22ke9OjDsNen/t3g@AqK4MUt533T8cOURjDEe5k0VkRiOBJprAF03OKOvStQLONVI@sCJxZocRvLg/CO6PRdQNgy8WYzkI24uIPwWh6lecRvBtKgE@QTVxwNkZaKoYuqBsLhKVfpfrrMaJ6hAl7U5VRioR8gFMs6J7gHwT1z0JkT3EHYw2BesA/BeF/QnGAHgrnNyexwD8K5JjUnwgBn0YBdzwfe@cB0uho3mEZT61susDWWyUjChizAeMXw@kimZ8L0nC3w2uHMlmAvaJ/EVjwCsrQmGg@@R9xCoXh2gsb5IpYnpwm7YfdmJiafgMTnlBOIXcxfX0rAZzEEoP2BKGXT4TJzXtthQRP8Y0C3c4G1DcRaZp8@3YWZYMQk/xUbkvt4DeE8Z6yEnFoRHH6dSVSvPNFHkWh2GmGaH5duUgeNyiEbZSkSIbxtRe267YC@CEl11HIibxxS6uxJ5FMPGqwcSo@IjrxZ3E/H0hT34IiTWmSWNSOn9XCqmsj3kNKEHrkZCQvch2VWpsgZhLFzydjbEDuk5gSfWQmeEa30cwv7sNKkAD9q1ESbChe0FqiG2wLBGeiZvF7jMoEDW0yXuT9evuIkgTlzgPH9iucAYLAFOGDPJsW47BMd1@A2PyDnC6WVLE3h8yi3EZmksHoInf4BGhcSTnTZQzyPPimS2AzSTEUPy4302p5schPF45J@duHq3Ggs/SSNOLJpfiKuewK9ZJkVWLgxpsJu75dDvx1lbqLqS@g7gTZfVshKl5z4EBa8nUPoe5ksWYRSgyUoPqTbsfv3dkm0yXN2pxQtXZxLHzmtxdv2XA0MsaokwxFnDlAGgKIcT5UVOtd2JDrF7tbzgVRuspEWRpe2E1eAyl5R4uIch3P71HnHfcOtOUSReAhaCqKG6UvMnLbUbUENlukM6xyrmRMZ6Qlt@sLzWppUmITCQBCkBTREyvLtQqFaxdXLKHvITii97EJYUct@twI@C8KL@hXwQOVT8CYisXRBzaaCzSam3zgB3VJE4dgbQVZydQcng7j0YeVJf4wdqkCPZiaSEh/3fNHOYCHnqSdOiAd1x3Rx4o1OdqKh9ZaK/mFFYJxtGGhH@4epDm5nzDLwPdJi9/BNfOjiVBwDdeKw0uUsk14JsdnaUjGb6FCO36QW8sPApytYbfeK4b3nSorZLj@nvox3PeY2cCIWr2oU0oTmvWmSB9gEagpzM1z7WhPXOeIubVVX@J4/mhQqKnh2BM3Ld@2rFmj93CK@7wUj@h3DYKFgDPsDj0JERrQ3kH1yPkX71Qu0SitGDAKdLYITxdFw/Yb7jvlcVK7IFaQinouhx0DUMSUJXPVMVbH@EFExX1dvKIFhm1YHkUDe@8SHU1BdxMm3SiCrHveyISlwcRCcXW7F26e5OcyCtJNgTO9QfHwvooP70BQi8r0Ypyg04YohXc/rI5PjVBum3wICcMI/Ojnd3Ts@NsQJtHxFAFcR@DwxmmDQhkBxFauYJsXVANyOySvlERYWYfP8qhFwkr9EI8xWkAmbwjWSk9MK93vyEuSK9DZVjDC@zqMTSWg5WbwFSMuCsJrugx6FtIuSabFkOZlMRo6R4tG91DAtCw1tX9o9DzDeodvhi5wWjyJyoBMpIvPPhPkHdcyzESLPw3NT4blEuMHDOVJRLMPq@FGkcjySmrqJ4t0yNYqWncqryqDQB69o947h@TG8K3fFDQwYpDlR5O2wKjlXhgFbiYBcLOTdjNrnIQuJNCGDh@F1Hi74uyRqPsQyEfdpMn98KqKCbLJxFSYhE1xquE6XXw8chZCEZbhthSfH@ia2441STIgIcZIDMYF3pWKz3a5GUDJFKXGozajbW09VQ0xJPdEm0dD5jaKTDWtGG4lRifLMEOFG1JNAPhS8EANBMJHRmGy52zLxWCQex8BirAWZrSJ3YicbOBRtsolXcdr8E/7Ixp5ETsZLzQ58xDEf8cLzlawkgUjoLqizyZSUJgN/aHNPUag7epEo7/EkxNlC4pWHI1CrQ1fiyjxtvt7W9oZuayGUE3FBISXFFN3DEEHpKEJRsu@8KsTAW@U3@SXlS7MHWmHXHrHYZeVKYjETL7ENoA3YUECfBcN@v@uIfXPsmpbLeDmLpVVc7IkgxpQGQzlAAxweP4susfgIiQx2iJCv0Y4jCgjwWmO6DpPhfVsgWtsOgBwYSs0d85s6cZtZiS8p2mwY8Iut6f7uGBK85njrCW8/NRS5cMuL2ubt2x2ACgQF93x@rbPXLivK7w0d63LnS1YqFNaLheVijGRyqrpgLK/Eb2UOA0qFYqGwWlxRlB2vP@amI5qlI6yVHALMshfY0b8B3rSv8D4spQY9BkXEAyUD27@yW4aiHNstmgNuDokiyMp4QTadUkH76NEHdCs8TwivjA2y/F5Y4DB8Yv/MzwawyHA5q@Aabd/2e86Ar@R6V/xmcLku3fbwHnOaiMYlYU4PTNSzB0CUJZ0lUaJ9/wIX0l1oOz5QwxTXdppN74rO6RBkAD3VweONaIFVwU2qCCGeGb/zL4YJ5Gd1TaeH7DQDAdzFElFAIgBFaw0t@04cFELiM3GQ95G2PIsuXDdlzeRB@nnUVqC5274D0jciMNUKJYvhDhV8@vzghJ0c7p@@rR3vMXAfHR@@Odjd22XPvmGnz/fYzuHRN3RYKnt@@AKkywmrvdoF31enxwfPXp8egodaO4GUKgUotVffsL0fHR3vnZyww2N28PLoxQFAA/DHtVenB3snWXbwaufFa@isv8wygMBeHZ6yFwcvD04h2ulhlnKVyZQoHTvcZy/3jneew2vt2cGLg9NvKMf9g9NXmNk@5FZjR7Xj04Od1y9qx@zo9fHR4ckew4IpuwcnOy9qBy/3dg3IH/Jke2/2Xp2yk@e1Fy8mCnr49tXeMSKfKOWzPcCy9uzFHuVE5dw9ON7bOcUCRa4dIB4g@CLLTo72dg7QsfejPShO7fibrAB6svd7ryESBLLd2sval1A4RbuHKlAvO6@P914i0kCJk9fPTk4PTl@f7rEvDw93idYne8dvDnb2TipMeXF4QgR7fbKXZXj3BmUNMIBaEA7uZ69PDohuB69Ooc94fXR6cPhKh0p@C4QBLGuQdJcIfPiKlxaIdHj8DUJFOlAFZNnb53vgf4w0JWrVkAonQLWd03g0yBCIeBovJnu19@WLgy/3Xu3sYfAhgnl7cLKnQ4UdnGAEgIn5vq1Bpq@p1FhPgBd3ArMqknOzVJ3sYJ/Vdt8cIOYiNnDAyYHgFiLbznNBc2jLeWXmktudC3jTq3xiKuTuQ3h2Dnf3QOPjh/Wpkf9r6HQ2kot3iTDoaMJAeBWroNRXnbfs5vDiHO/qxqF5mIyvYPeCiyyeeqnjXSlnyh1nA4qFckqQSp2fv6mdwzj35Pxczz4kZQKN@1KIXe53xdJFGbue2aJhfmJuKU6o7cfiLJ0sP9giPtfyOJx80Fk@37JFMjQOQcBymkgc@gTAWigZyWrEdFksS1piTs4V0Ylkk5NFcnnTC@DH/RS98L4h5gHCmdst5PM4hiU08GQ5FuIPmdCha@LkNbIDcNqUpRHY9uWFVohnh0N@MUGlyzQUdwDDwAtNvyd5076YSJ6bTE/Ioi0PKSvyuB15DA6/KBXfBMmYqBfDp5JpfGqPHrrEhjICpVDnWZGhkLA@0R7z5Lh/m88V6pXwqBY6bu1l7UcHb3EwVyitVCb8n4f@vG2hVR@eHQj9XZ3SNejxvMEjQANzcPgFJHHGfEk1n4@lAa2M9MkwMp4F1MFI104L@lTsqjs2det4AhE/jiGeHjpj3xnFsQcx/OVx7eWz1/v7IDkR25WN1fW1iiJONPIHP8ry5zeYDx7zTtQFLfraATWNgmKtZAf0nv2pwwhjpydi7WFEPOJbVhp54kWx4c5kriPw88v4NBAWN8ATnFw8xEzFQ5h8lV@FvKBIfp3ZMgUDaImi6lgavO8eNXwTVCXiAYvvQu6OqdZG@IOww@Yvm3hYIMFAgsXsXn8wBs6FwQXJPXVfGnTS2IbMtjCKoUo@7pvSBokTBmUmWbmijSO9Cd6O1SLotVjR2F6p2iklILEwiYU8BI@OtIQsjrxAtmDu6YDPjwS/gfMbcfgiBuFRWrXBCZBxP0yZk4cj8jln0TAE5MZ2Faro8eMwpy2GE6m6QIrP/yeP5ou3BkKFGzSwCcDS8iikcxhCk9BP0zq74ZyKp6YgnIrgWPEOnDurOAJKRR45I97lCX2Mw4oO7COv6zAPRUb5RkYJyZkg0@9ED4L/X5EmM@BvwYAToEfUIjnsuEP7gZQkqJxWMHolojjX0mIsZqYWUTPu9U0E5jZeMZ2wYMIMb8QXloAEonbG0uMbfmSrNoMAyOQ4rxFvv@Ed6x0TRk5Pqe0@4iv9vmv1@po88FR2FVNwG1nSubLSRA5fdL6EX2Cx7F7g@XVPaR8tyQwccIEUa47ZF4HKYWSKJHOw0PklmvQIWzmxJpKhKFt4xE4F0bRk4x8JC6Ool2nJ0FtQRecfphouh@CZjQmBL1dApAAh26d4gQXZIM9tRHRmudGSnmb5mejF8XRyEIHUL7NTMn8OzDaNmbErErbKaBSNWSKcL1riTMymPbjG7qLLoZONdgSNaV@QmThmIuYiQzVCCl/dAKpTJ3sdYk/TlMivIfav3UsXb7ew@RSXjGEkTtiMb3E32EuTDtvsPqzcapR5Bsm6ncz/wCW7dYuvV@LUHI3cIRcc6X8RRBQBjfMatUvohyIqmdYleqqSR53rnDOCB@WVEyWXZ0bCmIFOBJ6l9N/OHRAgr0zYwDL1zA0nkcq8I6t@IdUXdPG2G7q@QZeYZ65CoQA58EGDWaEGIcqoN6GR5nRrI/wS2xbQ@LQMmtP1tdE0hz3TbZs9pzsmq9MPXsfNB@4w6OMV4KqqJmcD8aAVNEEH3Ac2e@u4Le86YM@gOeBE0smr1ydHyYm/2MzXDp/5YuwryIM9o5yVKfBt3JMSeO0BVI1dYWNx3Y4fTffQPKGYaaFprTF64MYfnxgI8u2FmvGXr16zL23X9kEfPCKbS/bCsWwXxAcoU2SFGXS4pMHo@5j7icid7aPuQjM7FWY7NKkTzu0pIgMBLYuspUFTBIR9cWw1zs2PgdVjc4LGdIGjcrXkpFLH64vdFjhpisomn@JsD7tZBc/Gfntw@hwH43xgTnMz0K3JuT6cS@SqU49P1kJhfNMdjIEoyuTkDaB939yNwWizBUBU5pOTBnU9vBSnhdN@3QCKinclCSlAPQg0Vdu5wsN4aRruIXVEdrZi2iyiW0XsX83y44Gl6EjUnhLVXhbPZDeybHWTndrIu@yoa1owwmInQ0y@vAx64DMvGGDUlzXGCqVisZgrLuMU7euTmkENAb/yhFZFOXh5dHh8CoQURxBJxgj7TCQ@HYrKrbGAHDk8GhVK/x4FsowPErP0noiHKrg8J0Gt8BULtaxC3VsmTvdCCYOkOkxTsjgl7/l0MCvutgEWSjRHyDW4RuHLl0Yopxj0LB0NK29Rp64lxJN2S1KC94hbF/iqi@uh7ykx@YEAsEfkB6l8Ghm0xLFCUCc9uxdi7wxk727yCMrkmbIhwfhcKjBHOptGLQmop8fhtGy0kQjwdKZecGX5IFvMK2A5NGGRW46AZ0g26WFpzKbTdaANAF5Wx8MOh4srWRE0BRE/cVahGg/PMsQOiXCZcRoUtK6W1wujcqwUJdxsJ/z7wdjyWOoChtk40gr6tt2ik6iGfX7UEoYb0Mq70HPwbXjl6AwmJVUgu0kfhA0eeQeyb9jFvfm4l7LJ61yRpQGukts3Tzs4rOeAoEQnA2qkeCKuNmOEnWW4zqtTtZvAEJhWR0LM2UgJIPpZXJQCrKC@iSHIReySxe0@XarvyX2WmJAOewz6yQCExVd17WSABI9lF86pCJxJqyECE1s4JTJ8HxJ3J@bAki9YXrQ7xU1pGi8jFG6sh8Tcd/CIcj434LELD38xsiEpxtcIbVojnNoYivccFgHeZMzidEyIFR7QFotZmgEzNxPm8myYOQFTLFYeuFe0IQ5TEVvwUvDTNjyQj0iIqPhfelL00ra9rscXmMLSX3S9Jp6LCZICcsPHOBtVbNybRmAJQsdD@SbN5HmeW7JIAnWxt0nqLmwL2oe9zbbkjMX2mcsrSgRUeVuiPWGM@i5qTuTEH9GiyKkmDgdFrWPidFBEj/uC7EawqgApfNQyi1omWuLE44uck0l6iSTFiSQCuWSSZiJJSYl2gk/ULqZA0Y/PZMmkXkJWSVQDrBpWUEHpmSM@uinQBj@apsEjuRM7DksNwSAYsW6xcM8gRm8o0REYiWV7nod8JRM8svhWF1U6UrSQPE9qJE33SAxQrET4mI5ZcTVRIF2QgV7C4zV0iYwo1xYlcWOSKiwwD1ASxfZxr5YWz0Uvs1Tf5KuGGCvAji2edZ1ogKv0KvwtMU1kkIsjyyPhsQVCFALh6WiLOgxlebVIOVhQop6Z3mICDmpQ4fKbTMZ4N6BpiXYlJXcIkzunZDeAQn8OjnJS@P7qAPQ67os9Skw0nKDCh8fECyXPHsHwjNaYCQT1P@GMtfDkZ0aE0kMgX49ybsheI1mKubEnu5JZcWK9SkiFuyJLYod0mht5fm9DpMM5BJR3PHqMdC9wkliQTnbB6YCTjLQUZ0CbyT3L4RIqSbaY0OVpszMEcLLKJXLZiVIpsaNiRAknuxEl0XMmmESLveE1OOwLflAwB6QriVRI/3kVjuaO8YY9N16RxxPVPo8jQliy3u9iizCyrPe72IJHjlX73Wwhz4oOSUvpJ/kiUROcBGiUKEYMNKcUl0EyYBSPNZqIRQiNG/GzYuyuNgPbmFQVc53KlKoUkkgcDZfMgx4jXjEpsZE7wY5AvHpYG42otNDHWZd2KzzxQpQ@HCJtq8kugdfm5EFPWGiZA9VRQ8crScIEILH5JJgYM/e47SadGJTmAxYag@KpqBed5O7eBFjZqxT0aYVSno4UIb81E/nc9ClV0RCrPH3/TmhdJrBGgyfPb2FsVZmx4qvcg1UmhlWydLEaSpJ4DqTcgyDlHgApH4MkGvYy9JfkTPl4DrB9H4izs2kY9HgHAykBAyRty8FJbBwHX5vj@2AugLKVIps6k1uVhQkiPfk@GE8mYdC5651wNU54dkycdfto@97kqWdzKZvklRkYhVilptHKIloktWm8K@JJVYnGtsZls@OEI4HU/TXNz4kQidGUuBMuAqWSpxaFwKL2X5xDv2ysWpPtgSOemIYBbVn5zOZgICH4DBPfKhYmiAmy5DhUBCQJcXfopPCj0erk6RJ4oPzcZPq9JXnKJ3xik05FKBqXWAmOk0O4SDjJ3krKt1nDs3vzT83Mv@/1Qcdpz0SA4vdwHp9PSk2I9Eg1nRhaP6gvm9mfTZcrrrdNnP328Eb@eKroJSg6bkyHRu3a16L3vwuyKIusgd9Ck69LHpmD5BczkcSFdlNMbjF32GvavvKQps5TGPjgY6T5nKsoqRSrWTBkFicP0Q1QdDyyLbJENRgZIWDDPq7XBNy4Exs3zpHZnIEn4@K16xTbUDELmqPt2aYrjiISHeaFj@sXYdwsHo@Om7soB8e1gNCBHZv@fM/v/GjZIgQtku8ga2V23SNX07XwHItslJNAi@ua2jg5puW@cxScUKuhWOVJRUXyDi6GLnHNXOhLoJjrs6fAHqI93aUQARPPy1IMeCdA382j5fnEHPZDUoZV8wBSzlK3wlnuB6hb44eqW/8VKDlZoUrMLbQH0cGW7xVqk4N8uvBWHnzdm3F0y5vT/f3EgSfNsRwV9Gx/tVAo4CE4U7fb4QIFrhI7Xj4ZO49z4vn@9Vf@m2Yekybvs5t5nR3iAFExNi5NIJ/g0sQQ@pvYcVo4n@PirpwPAY/JT@BpMTLjdELj9jenxHwEEolnl9l7LCCW7z2TF1GD4siHDAKKtDeD1KiGXqnSTA7Igx5tPFEnNEkjYDRuFrsWcOGjun2jPBJXPNI8H17Ho99E2xDV53a362XZW8/vthZUvjs0mWB/P56gwKOgKSFvPAFdD5Fl9pXTjV2RgVEQN69rG13vgt@xhPfn8tlP2svk231cSdOwHzu2L/ZGfU2tv1OBMaHIGSxmhqkN3N5zoUIXpdIS@v1g@YFkgPaDYvfMvmYRnSYjQx8o9lJFLsBoGS/R5NbBOJ@yA0VGYw4tEUXn58Jwmt0fG4k6G13jg@e4GhQdgxXcLkdbv6l6qSRzoofEVc9GxTbSsMBhCJzwCMSHpbit4KFTv/0HZ7dx5gA3N9Icb7glNnbeWLwccjIeWxa7GrTb0Lz4TPy2PGpMgiNRmSuSlQKSRlSsb387BH1GS7eDND/ADk1tTsaulUCkXmpkWXo4aG@kAcLvVEZFtkDR/ICeaDbxdQ6a9f6Q7kmJ5BlNw6EBxbTcwQTnmEBRvrCq315rtVqNLfYzGVarPQNHLsdqz2psFz2ePWO78P4M3x9XS6urFW45t6vfgOcz6XnLngEM6oLwTrZdeIUwumoJh1JYxYv56mK2snhe3dquBPl67Vkjn78A19/9wU/@7p/@ab4mXr7Hl2f0Un8XRjIMI79o3Sw@vq3ge323kV5s1hf7jfRFBbkMxf1rPzC7ZmybmGH9g9yLK3fOWzoDjVavVtMs/ekTd50NIqcfOfESgyi52e13TErOCMJ2NV1LP34Mrq1q@sdpHU/uEP5m6P8R/JmOspzWi4m0tHxcO9k5OIjfExTeP9pGTRMX3E1hnOa4gQOFep@Sq@e5OjMM1six9yF6aNB9ziMmUWRptBjlyHwnkJSlQ8wkAGoOaiOHBmnVXL24ttrIpVIplZupOYQZt08lCyRuGMXN1XrBBdkfSQsmCiNrMUz0RavMbesIRgYkIsav8F2rGm@PDzKFg44mvFOc3TC671bl17iOY9frxa7WxTNEJu9dD8@tjW5ep4vXJUBr4myDSYDc9A7Gy1QnaAnIsHLFO3Tg09X0Xtx/w1bkWo3Yw@51xxddvI6StiEE19Dege66uCK568pzBjEHnrJpt3EpkbcRolhsGxypWjbuLnUtnK@Hjtbt4rG0XIWSFxGDTgYchjqDONmijbuota7Lje@9Njh1vDReXrhM9Zah45KoTnBdpEuHrvD0smUt9UEb7POYSFV4jwxXsQxkNi1MHh5NmzD2dZGSlshwNykwa7@ONnLFhjweXxesp3Z6vR7IE85koTEM6Gs9HNzhdAMQB1MYdJYrNLoxe99138@6kJns/yhrnl2J2/iCLAizc8SSJmXHt9OqOi8VnvzqmgNB5r4XBI4wARHVRfYtfP@tD1DP0grPTHBN/MrqpT4VNBVl3OWtk7OUPQJ@xxkmfpoH5A6FFNyQiIhmkWjTxy3OUglLV7q3HIVZ0x44Ft@ExHNfkFKuTwdtoC8/kWRuRqCWc0NLWdGUwxkT@zuFjSVVeQSH6IT7fVkwtDqhUmsSzaTxDsdXnofSr4dMEtbOWUSkCGLICQQgSRSBI037CAo@SjBo175wBok0Wb6dWezc5KW4laTHxv6ebAlj1J2gLFrdyDujQ9HwXtBbmjf3QRzJMJCUG9xueTbvycJgf8GtnMKUvEh0JMXGNH@EckmiE8caWjKQD5txNllD1G1hL@IEnI95nUSsyqJauDMHAi5Q5HJjifbIEwAhNSZpkqvjzbkT1ACxOtEMImlcSICPMTAyd7yPJFk1QV5eXbyznRLikl8kprczboL/x8w3UZVNHw9xhcYHsZAPQBWIzLSbEMO1Ir0hBDmzBV7bUgVGMezQziB/2AWdmpt/i54lftl6lGmIx0RWsuiihnOkg/TlUWD1dLwuJ5LK8kapG8nUuTQ/FeFGno0Q5xiuUQtRQUM4Pm0rDlIQaR7xrh76WpkbPwpBK8jXW3lmgzjyILQEl3UmKoI6X7ONREPbcpTxUZXdzmIYOWaWsl9SQugdaIoSB06w6KwfES9uXz@DdLfK/wc)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
158 [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
166 [yash](https://osdn.net/projects/yash/releases/)</sup>

Yash is available in the Fedora, Debian and Ubuntu repositories. So it can be installed via `dnf` or `apt`

### Explanation

Yet another shell. Yash is a shell that is meant to have very strict POSIX compliance.

When run on the polyglot from previous answers yash ends up on the same code path as dash, printing 78. I found a difference between the behavior of dash and yash involving numbers larger than 2^63-1, the maximum value of a signed 64-bit integer. Dash treats numbers larger than 2^63 as if they were 2^63-1, whereas yash treats numbers that are too large for a 64-bit int as floating point numbers. So the dash/yash part of the shell case statement is:

```
*4)echo $((    (9999999999999999999- 9999999999999998975)/ 256*11+78));;
```

Step by step this is:

```
(9999999999999999999-9999999999999998975)  
    # 0 in dash due to both numbers being truncated to 2^63-1, 
    # 2048 in yash due to floating point inaccuracy
/256
    # 0 in dash
    # 8 in yash
*11
    # 0 in dash
    # 88 in yash
+78
    # 78 in dash
    # 166 in yash
```

The spaces after the `-` and `/` are for Cubically.

Answer (score 6):

## 167. [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), 8290 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] TaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((    (9999999999999999999- 9999999999999998975)/ 256*11+78));;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#( ((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=9717
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \      @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#p>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8eAbIFiF4qOL3VVFLsmqmh4QxUokEkQWgUx0JkACxWLb7kk2t48z6W527mxuVrc9szqZ1kz3Ye0kmd3ZrpnMdF/P9kf0flyTaf7ByN0jIh94kKyZXTuBBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeEU0z6PzmNyn8sCOvO77oegM2sIMBa/nOle0b7NmYPTWdYLW0rCgYq@ZfDHu2OwjKSooVGXNcy2nBOxt4l7brfLR98C8x1ve9C9/ssUHHHDA7sMy@HTBvOOgPB8xrz062zNhez/vg5DBlz3EvINrA9vu@PaDwFcZeu12z12yZEyGrExn2fQgP2K7d/dT7NGCW1@uZbiuAmGuMvfT8wMb4lh0EHiZfZ2y0Z1sTQDcgquk73ovaqy8ngjYZ@xJQNPtde8TMZjDwTWvgeC7SpMBOXr0@OZpIUSyyN6f7@5O@JfZ1znPZ/tC6nAxaZq/9wOyaCfhUB0e@1xpaSJ9Bx4ZkSNO207UDxYKyb7O@qEkDHSzFfNts8WhK2/MZJmG9yy5zmNXvs2bX7BgW6zoQd7@wwWysAvYRwrudgI36PRY4PYASeD07jmPAXNtusaBvW07bsQgDZo8GthsApoHBHCjTtdPtspbdhQQRWlYWgLFhEPPiSBhKy1MYfKz@RCHCt0Ub4ri2JITdhxpCQnhYoUAVSY9r3@z3AUmg5AkgPnB6wH/OIB0w2wwc5HBIEthui2jYD3nfY6YbLyW7cqAGAN@hT7AD28eKMAgu69i@DSDNkPu0a98ZAAmQxDV2ZJs@O/VtW0@2g0SWkJmHOQywIAZV4dZWeu9wPw1VyVMYZn@gpPzl09/7SjGZUWWL5xX4VlW1ouy92mU3i2fo5mwP1d33NVNn1e9YkD87s@E7KjbzF/6tAlAVoEqX5b3@IG/m@oBgbgAI5k10oit3VTL63VjGbGuiLmIMxmO1oDbYgcveZKlk1tD3sWlHRDUvodBdz70AekJh/aGL9HDZWgGqwPKgZWaZfQVUg6ZAdeRdE4VPOw5UWoBVEmsEXEARQUFEAe8Jisp8A687pHiQMhggAwJVIClCPGizN6xtOl1MAuEIimPt28GwO8A0Q7eFNQ8CyG4ZTKJheS2M1POuIDsTgJIHtKderBUSUhAZKsKjomLQD//iz1oXFwCnZlme3xLs@oa1PItEqUnIgnxiyLCea3YJLYiXxdx5csjgyuw6LXOA2btjkQUhQblee8Nui3mQoX/tQNPqmFfQHNtt2xrYnMm59M2ynnnJZYfDORcK3jObULGUAeVNxc6xpztQS5atpIhncr3hoL3Bcv09lg7y77QnZe3JwpkNyOmGvrSYz19UgOGMJfKCt/RdnPOmlpCawcAMPKel9MeDjueWWM5iqlX1@rarpRMw0tm030zrBso0Ta84VctoO25LS28BL25Dxmm9YlWtulNuVCaSx7MEMNcIBpurrVm6qoDIoUZxle@Zjmv0x@xNTrhiYV5wjiTHYCPmjYSZ9LviHinqfZAvPWQQkENG0LXtvlYwijqKCYw3s9wYMKukEzBEgctOI5NOpTPxohMEKGmioNhYTx0PxVa338GOB4jiBn0Q3z7yrmUC9wQoxQegAmRZk/iaRD9IFpKJ13bat1kTBKnkI2qSvMlh@hwKSgEhakIyXrJF261YgwZhAG16EExJ5a53DRkTbtiHgQhxMXPzAqoIEvMC1XiBeI7kkyzapQuCBaE1bbaRazrQGLDZgWwXvB8rI0RfLvE4AI03lpgM6pljgGLxPjFqOMxpQ5vqgZjwx8yyUfaAELJ5x4KZDKkdBqD8oBpUyJVWV5NtbaqpDfx8LfdjENYf83e2KCx8LaEqQA/Utq9Z13QvhuYF6l8uJDEty@4PhMCCkgQDEEmT/Q555kQnagQdZfHpZN7UmYjuNZYHCntee6JLNFHKCA0s1wWhykyhQ7KW44N46o4nc4cIVxOZq@8xSgKB9@ocFKQmAExmj2xrOADpBox83XGsDvAuYudy@cg7o8nswSueO0j4XDvMGpEpbj8uKUY@9EI05oLIYY1Ow4FOFkFtJzyo8uMed0M2g94MwF6IInQIMV8jbxrAe/fA7HmuNwMoEDIEi1GSIbweQCM7QW0QOjCpflFjDVXEsIqgzkB6QMsH/usMBv2gDP2FM@gMmwZwSv7UHx8MDl1klvzAHzsDj7ubXa8J4jmA9pmXOeStYdMZTRSI/MI6/BAoV6CItQNWhR782yFwnZZuByA4yX8HI8eCVBLgBIL/qhCRIhlAKK0dkEjeB6FyMnYtTTWoKRnQ6NQsU7Hhqjo4MFVIlx2vh1KIvSUFATW@Zz5IrjZIKyH7SfSbM7u8sA8g/S6dNj54jqvdpBcWFtLl9DZI@IWFJ@DaQtcTdGXA9YRcOXJhPANdlCJLLgytUwr0a6Rv6xLySG9gtY2wd/ro9DWzXi4vN7JmvSieJXzqIOpAskHsHD4ATlqvVtGp6@r2NRTUaLaTpd9B6Xxi@U5fEOEr88rk74IKy0QGp9f3fFRkK9jZ3k2TXtWH3hCUV6uj@emzeuGscXZz1sqc3aazmFqvmNUmFAry03rGhe8NodvU6yvlXLGh6/Vl6Cyb1XQhvaRpG7kuZGTq@hcbesbk1NbSNkht7ewsDUQV9KlbHZ/gjbIlXQ9JBXhgBw26oZY2bjYg/6be0DNpSKunszDUqKbTQBkLiRBQoZEziUD7wIA7Jy8SQ8DeJYhHZgVd1ClyPlcr4DW/xD1b9AhVpzI7oJ7Vhf4SUIDushUOcVzPzblDUoRJS/XiGdFgDGOQH3YeKBidRBwE3HZGoOlDwx1LjQY7YFRqdmC453Vt4y3pGCoDzmfYXo2Zas0R7xcMK4gqERQYcPa7pgUtMwnuTGVnABAYNZ@fHaJXpgBP6jw0PLmvjNAzWKaL9Gs5pH4PnaCD5AUVCccEfhuoiro3dO42Ue2AWdBpXwCl7ZEz4Mo4MMIJJnluBpqO6l@Nq0@otWGXj0jJoTv1x54FAxcbun4M5aNAtudeOb7nIpGNPQANHFvBOpgAPou8wEa12kFpdz59ZwEHik15F2O0jUOdJK4VWCzvel3vwmNLEAFZ0zA4Yx@4FqAAStsAxokscD4SgWoXHoxgkjxoY38doJJXXFsO1WgTY@YpvvEBhAWbXegowpwynxz8eA9EfHG1UAD85VuBPmEhY1Amy4ieFosiiGYLTf@0M7QV2@p4TD2DDrK0zfIt@yqPzU2FnqgDml4OtCnbJ10iTCamppSBNwSlpGV3nZ4zOKA5mq6LPW/Uq8jQHWCvCMCRYw8UoS5HnTFO10SC0r3g8fdGKE8DxaYne3W4u3d@VDt9XlXzw8DPd50m1F/LPu@B3tS1A5WxFDu2IbVI8PGye@x5gypVCc4MTX9SGEnGf7F7/uLg2XHt@BueDaULnN6wa2JmPP4JvUs2iU0rtX2vF@qIgaDt4jJS005MD@LASYSuYOhQTA7G/NfQv4cTfoalXFgWy3n8NfQUEdcxIk4CGla/r1xkMhiTJgVDTxFzg0DixKDhN6XnJnqGU4IxNTwOblb4/EQC8k2xcIvAA3cY9GMluykWyf9q0G5jPxJ6l8j7MgdgQIEMvZfJm08pJrKSZJkKmhmZ19cpCK8XHgiqF05A87nxClTCHvFMUWW3nui91SikFA2zWe5q9vyAGgdEvAS1f@mhNhm5zmEsvIpQQhC9y@50yjbIdPpJRJ1CajqE83Cv2aafGRHKYsgJDRInQJEqX@H0GY56Pehh7WuKRsozAQNqOa6ZP6YHqtGz8EkOCBLINO32EDqfPGg36L4nWm5zg2K2m01nXlSgC6IunzOi@cPmLLKBMt@ZGjOyBOEHQ3/QtVvi@V9@vwUVMF09HXNMHW7oOAe6EW@059aWSIov9DO7ZinOh2HXMYkM5LoPpGXidJ3ZDR2zQaPsZLlcx/R72K@JygXmxB9om3fwGcfct7vDli2fszMhEidHpjy16/SoRPBExYwU7TnJJ8bVPD2pNl3PbBEUroA4dlTbvF7sEe@KY502iL8H4CmHvyyad4Zx3mDIf3Gq@b56dfr4nU2VcpLJCqtms2jnvcBsOvYdfOCbl8OWl@tfXlChEbW1edzOGxGO1nLtrnnJnefonE0AXkTfubiAUap4zot23QEFI@iDipK/pscdrCI7AEa9tHkXTL/Lf@dFkatvoWM@nZwu/XwOQxKLWNBqkLS4CJSLkcmZIGzXbI5xnNX5fM7CDKlnBcFTtTKZwjJ2Y@GkYbTc1O/PT499H6Xf3Jydmq9MEQDLa7dt@77WDD2S0zO7uVIr5pwrnOUsQOSaEZU035zVNQNgkoEgs30F1UI/dzEudjIWskvkuoNtI3Tk3PC86cUoTd@xvK4T9HlLEi/zpOTkxEwEBtcf6SdKim/T9G2Beo8deC50zW7onjXAKb45fPQAwcVn13D@MsYYhjePdpZ3jd@5qkPHu7L57@zO7ONMrB4ggnJd4gzHmpG8Zd3HrrhYRD@zqXg5E6uB1Z3pX2YvPc/v2G7ASkZBTkfgDL3Z7fLpvtODw/k8HThdL4CRAf7eRQsYAQQB/53NzXGyOaabo0mXuHt2MoFUnxlijDqnMs3uhddd27jIm/Azt8aHfhslu3g@VKKFEqlYvFcihYqP5xbFc64ov4T/@5iBJnZ8nMGNOe/oR2eJLzHzN7@AMDzAZZnZhdsvbFBKI8@HafMqwLc61@ZYPn@L3mIedWVv0R@T2gx6HSbY3ADHwOeq9G@T28rdubUeJpOmwK7fV4hY5V52bZDQ9DtVpaxUKH5mimKh8HAJ1e4O7aE9U2IcNj/YaP1yh6x4OFIFUYxFMWWRB@LhhEUY66MYFD4Ia@y/8e1OAWN2HWjk92ovM@VdH3TtPo6jj8BxhI7phBfusJ@o3Bjtjofu8d2U6/Rly/ZaCSQx5HMl0sb9OlJCHQ9s@s5T3fd6Hgx9vR7oDO4D6l8ApTkg/psATD4R5A8Ozpf5d8Its3CpB/RV0D@gVp3LIIeTbg8TPKV5Y3aKvLkJozLXHozxdx61ZwnSpud1P6d2QJ62HFTLQNlEm677amlK1xGrfiyanQhwpqPZnjcvwfsaMYAE6uFgeW5FH0GRBtQ5PKSWpyb57ui1YlN@940jocemyZ/At6R7Hr7H2LiLxoaxfifCXB31mnbX5I/R2spd8DaN5YeoRH2p59KsL84U87nhaKUiNSGC@mMgltPKBVbH7tn0eoeSb7Y@DAP5mBtp5OF3RrCRp2nROen6DrR5F38T89AxrWjguXaQH5j@hY3Dky4uDwjfeXJWzrbOJO5Bz7yw9@9lrmj2AU1CaPkt5pw9D1Hmq7QWJLtHkvCRn@de2uNAPmfrx2ML6nPYuxParHZu4STnvQ3byM@cZL5H7XM7Xsft2B2fGkf4Nq95AEcOuOnrXYUA/DtmcIk2MCSTomFdJ4hTt@t1uw@hLspELiE9b/b86x4an7Yg6WfBHZtNCBCPe6fqoOsmIlEfPq/tdOwh9FCBN/D6do7e5kXt4qQO/509pXxwmA7YW8f2W3z9D2f4zIHT7Nrs2gEUPgTxdbTZE0bNrmeimdUdSjxQRj4fMgVlef59vcKF6Q36fXqc97vDgH5oJjfXnj1FWWb7hOhDeMEZ8JVXzrH2hde0Os59lde0zYHrXOZF6xevs7k8KYup4A7L7aK30XWAVP7YQB6oxsNP8HEwu907L4Th@p36yM7Q98f3y4bkqmI4q8rXAtAxb/5FrBbNCKaeH80L5DL6HQsSYnFpLkORLo16c84ugHJSnDsblDCFECToLi8P7qGS5VmX96oTc@cnxUIkkspyYsul4D85iXE3Gs@FeIPBofZ8eBHo98Ufo6q16/S4ibzZjYyA7klZu@CcgwtJQde7jk00g0gwXfGYyXmlF/e3J1oNWb1zYaTMii/Oa4cH9wOzuk4/4L8s1y7NVCGmFxtn5fgNVuHdlDmBltC@Kw5fsDwmk/PQKDHIClt58HN8YRkdhNsPUmS2QCaK0mSNpdBwcoicM/B8g1E8TTMzGV1XeCKcg7twIZqMRQbgaBTKbcsD1nWCAcV12qxeZ4s3o3KhXLxlVaaWVdZocKhknrg36pPl9jFPWl80G9XFdC6XXkyfuWVWSFNUuxvYs6OaiXhthx4cz6jozDW5UQq6ZUkr3Ng16JBBOUjZFkjr16DjU4v1fG6yye2CT3Ex7z//ZUvY2YNGF7CeA1ULhMC9IV7P7njXT3i@Ivdav2@inT7CuO5gV4C553ZqLLhGsc7N671r9nr/dEMY64odLPByhPInhgWvVBxeoKXOgFcax6bl2ZwtRMZhKlkoy@sOey70o61BJzCAlcgIZ@hHxgfgwmjuwEdlopVlB6xl45IJ2VaR/tz1vEuyckRM/vNfchNlsrASli8ye9qiEMsRDamKZBdsWd4QsJZAPtq@J6JoSGRoIEMcnQJT29xfR7sjsp0GTsxJy2HMhlsP79ROWG6PpXGLDdojVpy2tlg7/vJNvdCofsd6efu//H5evxF0U7/Ira8FapbJKJVb5Kt48CoER6Fppi6OVFEs3MxBexdCphK7vDR0U3VJS@Ae7QMhvrOvyRKY7FdcbP@4wQKkYgAa3EAn0LzRVBe1IR8H5U4GbBX3IcHQwgQX3zlCdlVo1YpJFkfsE@sgr@QstPWBN06QLhpS96rP5FL4ctxgIb9rN4e0SndVMkrLVSrO4nl1a5tcvt3ycGND/d3ZqFTInY3W9xr5QBLn7Gz0RaH0I6CeByra4uM8NqC9V7s3i8Z24dOnwBwzVb1NV7gdBrTyxZujg6O9k9Pa6esToOYtL2xq3/N7ZiQpkBfIdKnjdWnHCJDFd@zgfukRSpDwDaJrGls02RZuTtN1JW63Q1EFqdWcusidYRQYq8RT35N8VvrAjoVPRxCSqe0wIUXZETGS4Jl0EJegWclbWC/Y3EGjDCmCVi4zRCHRSGVVoFIOqPRAGrHpUvIafEIeUI33E@puGLNAAK2iGNMRkEhhXlheHs4LN7Pwt/8AJe5Dv/a7lphg3FlijHFXiSFilIxS7NcOXrw@3ksmAnaKtgfCeNDHnaJtalt8oxHnLk/saZGSiYZSgbBdD2VrwK6cgIZayG9t7Bm6IFywOdJifYDShVu6slo3AEneaoFoao4HKNlApBtkfsVtsHIuU1NALCPsaLNMVTBuUJ3e2wCS69oCKfaeJ16keAQ5UGZsxjqz8z/8iz/jG7DOBuD@I@EeFZ7B25@Itza4/7kMKRbh7V@GbyV4@yl/e5dHUk7vNuGlCYmIBHxzcMQCGg0iiXrmKFZ67Nuw73RcGI84PaD1FZEOo/NiRZSJ4Gj1N0B5qC4gOwpplMuUn@03NNwrUM7nURXBKTyDTITsER8L0taBb4e4dQ66kvza6tpKEQZDdu5KAiTz3wu0SeEAdb0MXKlcOf3q@6bFtra2mBpYZteurlU4yfOL5rtl9X2I6CLEVbjWUmeQBpJEKSBsWyTTFs1MUcek2DjTxTRrVEAh4TUIfZpGDoiio7crLUih0/QEqYA9XHs0IME/ltoYqEIuGTDafAOlBJQDQBw2bvCa5PLIygSN8mJ8b8SrQX2L0U4wWlmdxWT1d@xscOY2xEY/Bgzzyxks54L7j2fs/gu5pza97Uyb3DSGpWFPT1wPrZH2AVumlfKl5XxxTY@1KVWAAnyxBX0CkNBmoA1atvPB6we1nb2Drw6PTqa2TVHM9GS0NEtvb2XOcka23ggd6Qmul0R9tp8/eflsX5IyjlU0mY8xohn9STRn5TaJ6Zzc33Lznum8KWAqo2LhoYBpRJrbp0WvaehRaD4WcYebH0zlquk3t/XG1vaZm5rK/tOsLaUpYwmZC1xnAW0oTbMZMudAGi2d4tkBgSFtXEtqtGE6tGrl75H3/I1P4UkE0e4naR6lkGF3aNetGHMMp6DsRp5nRVt/OGISX5A1EtUiohplaClTCzJxbJgoy/ShCcJ@OSTSIR/I0s5O04UxjO9YPHZAApoPd2kbIgx4DgbRGAnGXTgLQUPBMQ17QFSE8yAthwbppi/Nj8OQE7vn5E4lPig4ot1MYhtPB8rWdZoVs1ofsdA2@K5NPUbQ7zoDDXcYjQwcTkJpNB0LUNzCLTojfWuzIXZDMblpKUP7no6GQK8jr8@iIfyuLV3HMIpju0MADmxgs6@GPYjXpsexjb2EzV55OUgMdExLJOq400eUwei1ViF3o2OPWs4F9DSangWR9EWxGO2YMnHLj5sGOcxJ9SVaqcQJ81m7vGIUM@um4bgte6Th5oRyA6kD/unrt1dpXZ3iAdpqJnZetSb3nElhYQ5Eq432a00IhM3NUBAk287mptEJFLTdhhEI5Hgy8F@AE/pQrd0z@0wb0qa9gBmMXrUzzc0GA19nuW3sz66ZyzIZGrvAgwIMRinb5HK6OBWs4V53LV@FekbfwG3h46PTZ/WiYTTATZnobBFnH3ZA3cBxu66AagpJygQWOmD4KyNG1zBKQ4z4c5GyVWjbDcSaGUwN@aJDDRBoQaVm24@jXR6xFsipurlZFrWRFIebDNhia4bEALAzxJzUTYG@wvoWqIZCDGLtwKDUAYHy9GvbdaG9asAzPWidzBwCk/l6Vh7ako328FMOKY7ic2HOC4gm9/bvpW@6Hugzi/kKjYArt9Dvvz/Djr8tuv5x/r/NG/nKjbbYrY7zoIzp29pip1rMLC9lMovukrboojry@DEOnG8XQds5N1RDHUGk3GJXrwA/g3ZUXXQri@aWttiqlpYoBbxmMvoNJPguyBs3i@ZtfvExaBNZ8PF569QWA9puVzCM4i3ghy1kMZ8FnrnBbWd0FAtmv@hkMoiDsXiOCHyXPzvJUL9ydpKnMXpFKLn5i54UI0ldJayJqSNkOAGFdzmU6Kso0cWS7bmMHN/ZPyPsTu36azRwYTQZbwdBnL@SIQ8XLEKgoXASQkbj@x2BgCMNiIivWVPXQZj85jep4hqM@p6sLWte5slqoZJJrxYr6RRLPVXzS6qv3pzt5q6YnUvX2@aq8W3j6PLo6Ef6mcY2WTq1c6gWV9R3bLO0lFdS@aXCp/V8/v3796AOs/q2sW009Hou3ahrfEC3zrbX15eyaxtL2afp82gEuc50rVTSodLO2Co7WzfNpcxK6albgZBN/CyzIjjxdwO@Rba6yvbw87f/x9/@/G9/Rn8/p@9fO47TD1ot@Hoddsk@wueyzfCf3B9bMbeJ7mb7owbjDFA/q9Q0ikfp9Opy@uQdbqx9sgB/9A@f8BV/F8hHeFOU6c@Cktq2Uh9TxWIxNaa/c3QXR7HBc45eRvM@@WKxdIYHByyvLTxlQFUbhCh@yuWnIYy8ur6heh55dCCHVealWOswlssohx8lJY@oyNXNdoOdmvjHTpv4dzzAv9ybS/w7tvDv2SX@vWzi34uP@Hdq4R9htlHNMkDsu2qVI8QEYpOf2d6GcS5dCOX91vvq7/Zhn/MZKSkY0KW2txuZ3O1t3XiXqVTEP4jCSviGH@4CfBu3udzWu@1Mpk5417dFAbZyjW1eGvo1zt9tAdjMVn1ryzjf3h5t5xrvtutYyhv8Gd3ib0mF1nW2hM7qaOuYQ9yVIJHlGf7R5wXPpH70AgYwp9nSVi5V2q/tZEsnr5@livC2Gr1i4DK@Hu/Vdg9fQ@yjF3u1k70vD97svT4C/6Bxvv30acYAdngK@G436oDSF5ntTHUwGJz/@HzJwL5vk3eBmyEOE5/zGS7@qqR2t0ev87ktQPrF@SYW8JhyywExGp8YB6uk6qm6lnmSeVLoFq4Kxcvi5UvvMPo/PBxBgDMqfPD8QqfQKbag2bCC/bowLoxHhZ53WGyB04a/Qg@cTqE9WjlcO3w6KlwU3IJbLCbAzf/vHXovDz0A6EGywagwQNiFNjwvDg9fArA2ZP8B/pxCoTACPEeFK/gvdIv0eXdegELruLsU3gqFszOlztT3NohAo5g2CmljLZ12Gqtr/W9vbktr39ZJY1vdbNRxI3FDZdn0@Vk93aik8sHZWZ5La7W0olZop/Ht7fn5bu20dn6ex4mu0dZi5mkm9xQ@1e3Mlng8SbW2K0/OyjlkP8mIqfzWk7Pt5Ry61zJA/RL4beUzn/mJQMJze@FMSWvXb9@@xe/b66tr7iIH9zt7G4biz9s8eHEXesEHo@ZnpU86RtMsp2n11cbNLfRaZ@lKWvRrGqNd@2rxbFRqs5KKYwdtUwfVobiMCuraKtO3t9dWwWNtQ89pBRxb8CRnar/fP1MNmk0xyF6zWq35vjnGEZS2AkC0zdVq9Uw1/fMztV5qYNrV3OYa8/zc5rKu6vq74tYW5IFZlHTwVtMj1fPT7OY2/qfd3G5p9NHxT9fRUwe2oee2rkEEfRXeRjca29K2NPQDL0x3c7uNTop3A666pjf021vuB7@avsWhbutAOAZqwz/SP3Qn///5f/maBaB93KZQH3bZyqquNce2vrKmbWQ2xV91AQirqcvpZVR00ma6Xn@6tLy0vlJ/0lgylvCrbZ1tN2Z0ujqoP9CSZdurFlNYsSjKjMqxWiypaXSnUhVLnFPQ9S7Y8mYF@2lMqMIHXUqaQYVub4UsHHVA@jbWP6MaZXqD6bc3wNY8EHRmTSw7nZ2NCgWZSGeVZnXxJmXeVlKYC7tVZRLRQigPLV2htUn1Rl00/Xqxod6qizfNWxxgLBV10i1XVyqVpRXuXqR0TNuc/uTYhMfG5vqqnmel1bWlYjGzvqHrAKe4pPOpetAeK6F7o1KxA9OqoByrpAAtTUtDTeipM6XatC8AGSBXP97CM6urqwv5EjxGX6ztlUYLW0v02V6a@dkobWSWMk/rS5ubWKUN8vy0oFRw4ZCvUqo5lQsKtrFJiKRwiYOvLSwegWoi/pZ2l7iriN@9hUDpMxcGrusF1vK6uAfPa7cXwLNjBqxp2zBCs7tdeSwGDCK7rWunZS8o9d6o3aB9ztVcvbi22sgBm3wYtRmxhhLY8OkdmfbQtq@Hw2s7/Ow4gfnhg9mnz6j9wy9/8sMv//sffvXTH371kx9@9fNff//zn8D3L@H7U/786b/fXMXfX3//L/@XH/78V@D51/D9T/D9j7/@/t/8Pv/S@9/A9/@K@f2N@Mbi8a8CsP7k19//7C9@/f0//wV8/634/mLy@8O//g/8//8Wf@j81Q//@m/wR7z85KdQ3L//q1/i/8/@6u//0y/x/3/9n//@r/7V3//JvyPHn3HH//Nv/z3//bs/@Mnf/dM//bs/@H7O70/u/P3@Af7f/yP4PBzPh8B5SLk@1@f73wqf34UaUS7AA8Bpf/zDv/lD4NV/zd/@GbzBfxj0R@FLIoS//FH0AhD@pxmJ/vjX3//pX4Rvf5iMmAgDIH8EYX@eCPujH375@z/8xX/3wy//7Idf/gm20tzKZraWzRXvHkCkIOLqA@JhxLWHxIOIPMoCW1BK9MQf4ckWyDVaUlaXcZyV458M9/y0iNonO/ukrMJ75lMezzth@U8i9Aw3yxQhdHmFQgugSBcwdBVfZWgMFVyUfvI0od9zRJY@PWUQGRLHIlPEJxxR4Z/5lBDrmJLCF0LE4RtlthCmX5hBmCfsKQRDH0rd6Bb@4gv4PINBnxj7Vbc3WFXJso0q22bPMGIV3ikcnfQOPS4e9VtVdtkzHK2i9y5QiA@/YUz4HsfXGYq@zaOybQXCvwOPZxwMQUNQ3yngleE@u/D8TsQfKQQP/4UOi278ygD4yTDuB6/Y6xAc8aPwGDyYyUecmjjSxniYboT/LAIk4GQUIEQmGx@chVlkIi8lfM1M5RLiMxGWicKY6DwToDJsCuBdgQlvZTIhmwlFYDA3dKKYMnRGjjI0NZ0kDIoTKJNJEgxTJguVUTJo/rYkMl3KLJG1y9LnfgROlMFMctzxidN7KSp5HG6EfQSV8OUJMhQ3ypsgalynouUCVlxbCQHrikanYoF@iqYbyjdeuVz9rriyrsCT3od43pY4@QlYFQ9TNrbgg7G3b3LYppXtk71TCDs9ZMVSwWD1QuNmZb20srqyWlpeW1tdLxVX1jZX1lY3lgvFwlphtVQqbq6soEJ6q2z/iI0MdnT0e7lbADTK5fIlhMiqxdX1yrgKKclL2SbFjCuE45sc6IKIwRlpozdoa4BTMzc0I/cIPkx5pLBH4AWf3K2CU65MLHUdHFbEggiaxYUKOF8dUYurmyrp67lcoJzZbosDV9bZ6yP4OT748vlp7Hm6V9t5rqyxZ4evdiceqyLSKnuxt38avq7zUJl0NQTxzd6LF5Ov4oFa8QJbXc9mDcOAH3xm6UNPY/GdjFI05vdS6lqhtK4Ws@djG1Tjm1zu9sJp2sU1GBWtqI9ToJHj2V8n/HSzAQyYR20i@uZ6cV15ifYMm0VuiOoEaHEHQK5dMnhs4pGpw/58T3igFzp956IDbHjthRGCILi@Dqch3so5h3Du4S1rmiZ@P/cDOdjxz@BujwHPg/ymQrrT0ZXnMMzo4dFguOtjgLPoTpsVFAN5tFTa3Fjd2FwubWQ3NjdWVmFAsZotlrLF9Y31zUK2WChuFNc2VjeL2Y2VzeUVaA4Qurq5rqSA55x2Pg9tuKiq9HRcC8@c2cLDezyjs62kWnYbTTPZSGvpLNUKPYYbTF3eOCswSKgqaCS1NKqqpRU0H1susqKqqCazWGp/f6ewv6@qz/AFZ8B2CqrawpfVjUJh/Zmq2hSyA022BIk6@La3hlNlqurgy05tfx8hfMCX0gbCUNVLHsJfuvJlHaK5@LK8jACYqn4bgisAcI9jtEGpBvylUHi2o6pDjt4G/EG8Gn9bIWT38AUDMNE@D9mBMFX9UiYCRUpVj3k8kdVzWd5aTVUP@EuthiC@osKv8kJ9jS81@kAiH96Ac1X1AhwXPgwhVbUJTuRfVbXAZY1N8OuBC/e5uQNTVce8HFgSVR1RbNO6VNVz6Q/5AD7Pn5udQcu@4J@xz58WBB1AkDMa7u03v/yyeXHR9Me1vS@PKeirr56bH8ZDv3nRFAmb5/DxMBUEXfbGkx8bg87Pze7soK8hyJ0IOh@f24ThufktYCY@F5hR7/wrDPoKgmatewiA8OlB5CZ@nvXg@cxs8iD5oSB6jppNtYIsi02nrRHjmll60El0@g3D5etAM5@QtCqjpPLaWiE73NBzq0@GG@raulpegqf6RF0GJzQNVkgXGFPTZ6qq1zcbT9T1VbWcfvIkl35cfMLU9U21rK6vg7TXK7co6DT9pq2NsqNqATzy@S1s0NgE4Rn2P6KTKG2oID7BW0bgLT9su9B7gKRm8M3lFAzvVwXGKtPwQEw0A6c1TS2dXi@l03q6AmkXVMBFoEKW4lhkibEKMgMw3ixBct8eDH2XFSq3Uzn7l@VgYPq4qE05lJm6Bl0aeOMpo9OfpzDAyZaXmqtb2/9k6vPf/JNZn9m@@FF4B71WVFK3SgvPmFnZVFI3yu3N7da2zPFrNh6bGTmIYI8Zu8gsKotpLHh6Oak116q1i@OanCmr7cDYbdlb8VKLi4tKaut0W11WD43zcHJ8O0/rLWe4GIMLF8bZ@dZC5reaOc8Z20/lUhOgnld8Gy28W3iJA5/A3ljFirhgQSrzW34gE6UKMJUKzjqqKWw9Vtcb4prg1hkv0NZ3KZrgZkc37aFLJj7ll6i/aGaZ99X1BrDwd6@c7s3Gcm6bVqY14LDbW@IK65CWDZWU6wknEBI0wYE9Gmig7qySugP11T/ZfLf@buPdy9eHrw/3nxbKG@UNovqZZJRsMV1MQz0@hZ7KOd4DJfOTt1r8zv2qkir308sr6eWw3s6qKU4kcCPna/V6scHqy41GHbitwXR4rVZLT4qrG5mVcnGd6alttMMvraf6QG90FtcLueVUQ8BZWdfBTdOTpWLqbfJznXi5oqU4JbXx8j0OZuWlA06JXPk8Y4u3W7fwv31b39q63UKbUnjgP/@5veXh9I@lkS/0iD6JeFGcKPy34zzjPNX4LrfF/7fwZ@eQE0FdW1X11PvqNvDDu/N35ykltcnUElVhJs8nIPuMcf1kyaU/O1jCv3eRxxIoXEvhm721FLDVbRjDg18@nz/Tf68Eysvm5trGWkr5DZDrDqs@CA3NXNq27QfD3iw7l5rvvDTRBsgNbV3A8XL4EU@VfSrvlZB6DkNFBw25UNOJ@wnlJ@ZF17Ek/cZBHncdoK@ioMuhO4NYm9gQZ/0HZD3OlnCLK26u0pUb5RHAGloD2rAAPxVFeYSW8/iqyXhZ9jgY6DgtUdCVR4@EDA4GRjA4R@CYSHjmihXlVkHymK1WwOhcZ1ys4juyTLRD9/r8LIjumPFEATUUrrTRZirMN4bwEmtzLKA0S4xyJMyxcDz7Rzxac9hGVPYPXuxBGhjntMniRKRW/Saeek7FW2jrLOxKgAZ49G9VUIqiY0QAB568T9Z7uO3L0ihmhhUxvE2WKxAry4pZwiTL2iJhHV8bkBzBt0G0BQCY567xErClc5GtKIPAhwoBJMTSUY@IDtO/sLKi9vCcxHpDZzdyc4mGoWyLlaLdLwIWVAa/sYgSWr2WOMG5GpGZoBUbWajaCt@koIXxhE9EqFtlaZDtVXhV9SvK15oFqoPna5Xveo8fW@/69V6joveqA3xmMj3opS81h0dZGlR7VWCPft1pVAb1TMZpVHv61xq@40Hp2KULBSjQRdmg5G4VcEFLoEDPfqy7ue/cRna/7mYA5WF26cfVj1mzWkDVJetUi9lu9ttqUZQD8hxUP2bcirkFX7TeSmwAAcUkY1YSXpjkUutWP9bNBupCXUiYyexDYQDPoN7NZBo6ZN6FwOmEle7jx2amuz2qdHM5HWO9W36yXx@Ao5Gp4ntZM7dGTz7Wh5C@rMGzCtl0dUAe0gla34a4A34VoDGv0wh1jiOpaiNAr1etLv34ydKPl6oLCx/ro1yvkeXkLxcibkDkR4h8JbbBRlv6sc4mSELrd5r6hVP@wgDhqGadTAaInO3HUnIMl34MIf1MRmJ9i/KS7lGRloHIYWJTCD80mU5gJUNfOrk6oAPgBy3cHgdpa4HlOCI639fYd2DQbOI25yydjm5SDAwTFzth4NnoyRNFZi32IUDOKFyaNjNx8E3Xevi4kEiXhPEd3ffJ11liWMrccNBJJ3XD8HZ5LdZcSTRRgwt8q45RUAzcFG4rXGLx3ScgbEh6QBySHhgvh1IEiSTkhIhZFYFQW7KCIBXKiTY/jYD2XaN8QvU6bPkgQjga0JhnoOFkP1RJNgE/OeBizhblBw5oKsojKATigGVwGmwbBBl7/JiJ160qK5bWsS/AaBjvQ6aIkaYwhcwfgCnAQCw/AI@iPKRMALdHGIK7qxIZrfxuGYnNkRokyHzI8j2SBu2R1IZuwLcGI910jgbWxaNHHzLVFYEQ/NPoBNJD2O1vUqK7L7Odw5dHr0/3jl/WTuAXRmsb8QsQ5CVDU1eL9PHKkKbj0g4hyzwu2t98ZTGmge47wONU8Q6xFvvq9QtWKr3azeJhaED6FJ@ahA61HEKyAzpsOjA8/yJ/7Vw6@eSNhXjdE21GovsRc/KmBESHOudutGE52q8c4MwXdObiBKfEpQQ9OwjEjSk5eQsdnZ9BW7d7uAMZWqG4YYXsvKWpKhlG43J1lsztfefCoavFOhxAIj2dNT/gyal9KHgzSsscmMjRyuZGoVBmhSw6itJRko5l6ViRjlXpWJOOdenYkI5N4ShKyEUOGca/y8trkXM9cm5Ezs3QuVKInBGElVLkXI6cK5FzNXJGua2Eua1tEFyWktSkpmv7GFZc2ZBheOAADIDQcxXAFCc9VwDR0lRMSL4y5Qn5bSQ91zcLIqOD/CFGKpXWoneQPjJuVeNYZTkeWZ4zfxOe0FcpfKxHDLvn@yCV9kZ4FRQwnV5muAFTUfAwBatrm6AM2APQUqr7wP@2XuYHE/jjcrQJEyFUi@E7JMebCCBNkW414@wzI7g0K5hDK82Exk92YCFhYjtYBZIcy3Kip@UQVxJ@cagLKGCRonNilHgMrIPklleZ56k/nJnl8t1ZJgDOzHIKKQ53dVYqpI1GwKsyKfX/BK0q8@N6ik21DWqAuMOSeGCiQvGEiupNsaz@@vtf/G/s19//7Ffshz//1f/7H/9HdP8H/PnfQWdhpTDCT3/GaGEdfv4Vo2V0WtKPElH85bL6wy9@Ca//w79jP/zkZzzoT/9Cza6EgCAEvaKUP/9n@POH@PN/qtnVMOLP/5hHxCRq9lZJqFYaxPrpXzMGuSGUENgv/pIxNQMKhiY4r87beCO2n50DCMlQJ1djMpz/4g1AQOOCnlEBrngrRm8ZrAA9Btw38VLGqO2BOsOXjFBKW6bVwT3LwssLUP@xUIXxAuMC@O26BUqPmK1IQ@n/gJVZOoNxdDTebuEYh2S4KL8otxqFYtyMmgfs8BYRAYruRwoxgeGtAvxNI4FxYOCwhUakRc4jgr6v8NJX2YGokrPouhhF5CVT47SMuDqP7g@SQ11kWuyG@MEWdG2OIjbVFmMZJsTNRLVBLpM@MGSMtrrHk5KH3etDlUCykN5IWHwhKmQnwUU1J5rN3uH@RIPBTxNUzMu4RAozqjJVvScuUlrE11HjWk7G5/iKCPVCebmR2Dg/K7L6ox/9SFVifgXkIb@lEYRYobjICIOKyaBSLKgUCwKcOUySNaul0gQO1HGgXEweEsGTxURUMlnEXNhyZD0gGjAW5LOi2XZ3GHSq06BJIieF3TTwGMhioyrayZlLMmebqfpUAoCZTFOdrMvZoAtTcaYranZKpHbCJ1Fb8yEl0sQaBVFPmaRSWHPFzVk1l8zwDtDFRuaBGZUKv2NGuQdmtLZ6f0aT1YppE@Dn0/d@sSPFRCjhI2C84acSHRR2jb8A1ovEEWLsk1PTYchTE0Oe5rXHtBl3JIJ/Xp5@mrgY0Y@diYqDmFfewObTA0/7Hgw5PNSCYzcrz7pSXVxkfOF6vh3ED8Rw@JZhN41HsljehQu9WhZPYXXErZ@4FM8P30r2K2HPJrTQHX5ZM4LmhELN8/zccZ3B@Tkon922HhEQXw0L93GmFbzlGVyx9Fqo2h72NQ9Pkx7o98MkfZcnO3WsS@2wLwLTkEmNwYDOsrsw@GIdvP8t8DhJsIj8RjjQSJsDjY5863g978J2PTyNBlNPgD@IYCNCZr9PuGSZmWVWDCMxiNasrKmLpF9/dlL2dQlvMJTpS0kACWJkmT9JY6SsPyO787nZ8WQyv5PPx/ckju/J3fi2HT8YTOJMnjjbg8/Py3pZiyBAxAiN5fvRyIoDqKbQSaASeuPdozzBg1Fs2YEF3R9iWoOoNRHdaAN/ZMO3gHZsCsTfzKP/3RUok@89tPpImT0Zg7zp0VWBNEQL6Pg917I1iH6g65GhWCy7kLV3H5iXGOjQCC/LVBJcLm4HhobZ79su3lbHPxLwPTyPNkJTfE@GQ1UeOAMn/yrLLkvzq2j3vGV3zbHd0kTMbAyuLPGxbbZIXj2s4CjoSOh5/MJZrZAtJlQxOraBIpXnsIyZvdL1@WzFozgh99BiHGF4MJ9@NHE3KZpxErTK10A8HyRoik52o/P0@uP@mB/10uUX3Qs5yvsfXpOv8AScewkCdOAXMhazUbb6XeLzWAuL9IAeIYxrJItMG6Zlt@WBNj5Vh59HovtLSrMMYaKqrOWEdjKvxp27ajzGFZInuVbyMJa8j@kezHMxVuPAIhG283ldyBTkHbPbtSwtDpH73FljnjslE9APa8xz5/Qq5zMEapiSJN0Ab7@qcv1CVxxwHsDzCp5v4IkAYQx6zhlKlg31WjnlRSE9sx/TWoRP3UJdNEZFPb6OGIulSDdO5N6GeVpz87Sm8rQSeYYtIJllLJJiJbIUtYDVc1cVdO32YI50xiAcucPjLrENH9czfVx7vUk76bKTZemrdBkEctpOl/c0EMrpVrq8S44gXT4hx2W6/DU4oraV/pQuy2aBEXx4JcdT9BciHN@tdHlH028VvPE@kPka6XJYpxDnCX8litzy6dWmWPX3wllVG28TRqUyy5BjAnh4WKx6I0vfAvxTVHFcKgQuVFlpiSLjACTRacR6DJ4PdBsG3gfta7O6j7KcmhLzG9EcCoRnqrFJFeSSIcmjdCqdFEYcMQylyUd4AoIoN8uzMWLFqZHZfeiI3B28xxmIncyfqGeQPtDSKLwOkeOTON0ovayvJAhegQ/DExPPw3MKHZkdYYTGAPoMtJCo79N3FArreuLoTV778RqaniPASszJKLyWCGxMpoMOh7opZdb3@kkmoVBc7XPiafAjGiVy70QykgqiZc4JJm9RMhQM8cav31WcWDpELSGCMLBeaPBWFvYLJIsxKJJ1MU2VNz5AISZzWnQWlo1suyucFI@Lmyz1FfO6IZmWZ0mSKykmIbGBG82H5oDnHq3L4Pbzzxu@ypSgggOOCCCWMsyFy1fvM/R3j@vvUqGWRJjIYJZiPbsrnVav7@xlJzDvRtlOVyAGZtmuPlM5CnOISA6jg5hmfhevTan4eFEqV/J5piH0CW1fki0cE9xDt8mxBYeFWoJ/lfS8xInZy9J8Qk1rJN0rQyotBuYk4PCCh5hGRbsbV17wWVWMIdhHw@OzK9hPVnC88hAeFcCfIDlv5f7QJfOqqG3TiUbRygVfdfDQSiw8SDbmCeKe7NdCEy3wODw/3j189eIb6HTX19f16aUIbLWQNurHlTuXCcJhSymLZwHi8cVkO9Hx/MHCmatOm5SRBygDJq3bcPYTbVwXsiwmzyfaLqTjcWMUFbAuo2ZgJqQSqjomdtmOoCu/nUdbMgUQqd4CvbM0WsNVI@QOXNA5P6fu6/wcjXPOz0UvhlUTLiP9JiXu6S1F9hpKKmnNRBpXMHXgFk4ADHu0bUhOwImjtLgdSgrgHAxk6jDV0B040tgB54doK5pcy9eWizg7cdAOfQgPNMrQSis4hC2t4rkdPBXGxolPMq0U@SxwRQdPlA/6nktnAtM5i6S24/n2gZx6JbSH7rVJZiA8FzpuJIYRN8iS62Keyw97D3ha3CRHU8iSNllmXxi04lPahCHHpdPnR8WGph@BTokIYbLRAho3u3YPUDoB3p0xm/zSgVrp7DsXF8BIeXHlFDdwOTUhac5r53bkEWgp9sbsOi15GLewCaOD8MU8MJBTS5xhF7DSGmhTm1mgbPQFwqKZDMNz6gpkpEWx4LsOj3Xu3MjG0i5oYz35LMqPjvAWtHOsWb7R2PHxeqkr043RmT6f4lPTYtGS5EBs5VKemqaI4zOrtE5poI1aX1NTqjxODZ3cbMLsWvJ0Nw3PFSwrj1wSPGgBxixuWwMKrotKGy2v6aFJqsu@YMslha4A8GhymWcLMPjKXgI6hEFSRJZb9wkBo37RUr/AxUTlUQplIec1TC9ZGd10LHfEy2xBgOMLKtiUeROQL6uxl2UYajyakfGCpmYASkbV1QQkiC9WPx5xyTudFIQiiIfPNcW2fd@laMoViBJGd4UKM@LKHYa9ZNmL5oMJu14cTMUNNdvCfo1fsJNVX6MFVplnQn2HgadlouiuTMruXFGaa9ID7aTZEm0IbSc6GtXHxCEaC457FwLUoxCHopwh868vgjJ8AYesBAlkIosFjWij34sbUQTtqPFYgEKjEutStGIcG0SwHYBAaQM9s@oXaLX6GBJSFwv9nT5LbSpUEukBuaDvkiW3mjNUSiqsjhFSEgSvTfQPbV8VMniXguuO87/NfHGjsLZJ9tPMzQ6yvfpmI7tkVVVmDxzT7QVD/7p1eeF1rkBZYP0PzZE1/vgtY6srDLeYlB7zrc/FtWqedjev0/EAm3TazqI8e4A20J@pjNGWWDzqIM1YuOuosoB7nuGTxZ@yWpniUrbUk1zIjah79bVG1a0WKr2626i4mYw@yFQHmWJGQ4/HRb0CkpZPu9QHDbKKzC@xl9J0EU/HxLlVr82OPNfqeOmA0S198TU92komG1DP7Mfb0xWMOjw/7tNGfjJ7iYY47YW9sDmR0vFkvMG4b6NoDK0@u3jFKf48Gq6tVKbDsYSPHqGJckXopvEC3Cj9YbPrWCCDiJ6oYqC5YrksjO4thnwLAgr9HO7JcYEeSMPgigy1vP5YJHZ4lHNZlq0YyG0N@y49@5CYMlYTePIczzL3IRqPwsmbiM4ANHU9OscK3S9sN@xncJ@EXkErcrYgw@SOCoyPfEP7Gs5B/aNdEPDYYiIq2RgzXVj0km/dQaMCUtW20zzo0Ydhr0/9u8HxFRTBi1rO@6bjhymNYIh3NWmsiMRwJNJYA@i4xc15V6BYxqtG1gVOLNDiNpYH4R3RabuAsGXibWcgG3FxB@G1PErziN8EpEEnyCeuOBoiLRVDF1UNhMNDrdL9dJnRPEMFvKjLqcRCP0AolnVOcA@Ce@agMye4g7CHwbxgH4LxfqA5wQ4Ec5uT2eEehHNNak6EAc6iAbueD7zzgel0NW4wjabWt1xgayyTkYQNWYDxiuH1kUzPhOk5W@C1w5ktwV7QPomteARkaU00HnyPuIVC8aAEjfNFLE9OE3bD7s1MTD4Bic8pJxC7mL@@lIDPYghA@wNRyqbDZea8tsOCJvjHgG7nAmsbiLXMPn26CzPBiEn@KzYk9/EawnnOWAk5tSI4/PqSqF55oo8i0ew0wjQ/Lt2kDhqVQzbKUiRCeNuK2nXbAX0Rkuqo5UTeOKTU2ZPIpx40WDmUHhEdebO4n46lKe7BESe1yCxrRk7r4VQ1ke8hpQk9cjMSFrgPy6xMkTMIY@eSsbchdkjNCT6zEjwjWunnFvZhpUkBftSoiTYVLmgtUA23BYIz0DN5vcZlAge2mC5zf7xsxUkCc@YA4/sVzwHAYAtwwJ5NinHZJzquwW1@QM4XSitZmsLnUW4jMklh9RA6/QM0LiSc6LKHeP58UiSxGaSZih6WG@m1PdnkJorHJf3swtW50Vj6SRpxZNP8RFz3BHrJMiuwcGNMhd3eL4d@O8rcRNWX0HcCbb6skJUuOfEhLHg7h9D3MlmyCKUGS1B8SDdm9@/tkmiT5@xOKVq6OJc@clqLt@25GhhiVUmGI84coAwARTmeKit0ru1IdIrdrecDqdxkIy2MLnInrgCVvaLExTkO5/ap8477hltziCLxELQURA3Tl5g5banbghos0xnWOVYzJzLSE9r0hee1NKkwCYWBIEgLaIiU5duFQrWKq5dR9pCdUHrZhbCilv1uBXwWhBf1K@CByqfgTURi6YKaTQWbTUy/cQK6lYjCsTeCrOTqDk4GcenDypP@GDtUgR7NTCQlPu75op3BQs5TT5wQD@qO6eLEGx3jREPrLRX9w4rAONsw0I72D1Md3M6YZeB7pMXu4Zv40MWpOAbqxGGly1kmvRJis7WlYjbR@Ru/SS3kh4FP17La7hXDu9CVFLNdfi59Ge92zG3gRCxezSikCc170yQPsAnUFOZmuPa1Jq5vxF3aqq7wPX80KVRU8JgImpfv2lct0Pq5RXzfC0b0O4bBQsEY9gcehYiMaG8g@@R8ivarF2iVVowYBDpbBCeKo@H6Dfcd87moXJErSEU8AkOPgahjShK46pmqYv0homK@rt5QAsM2rQ4igbz3iQ@noLqIk2@VQFY97mVDUuDiIDi73Iq3T3NzmAVpJ8GY3qH4@F5EB/ehKUTkezFOUWjCFUO6ntdHJsepNky/BQTghH90crq7d3xsiONm@YoAriLweWI0waANgeLqVTFNiqsBuB2TV8ojLCzC5vlVI@Akf4lGmK0gEzaFayQnpxXu9@QlyBXpbaoYYXydRyeS0HKyeAuQlgVhNd0HPQppFyXTYslyMpmMHCPFo3upYVoWGtq@tHseYLxDN8YXOS0eReRAJ1JE5p8J8w/qmGcjRJ6H56bCc4lwg4dzpKJYhtXxo0jleCQ1dRPFu2VqFC07lVeVQaEPXtHuHcPzY3hX7oobGDBIc6LI22FVcq4MA7YSAblYyLsZtc9DFhJpQgYPw@s8XPB3SdR8iGUi7tNk/vhURAXZZOMqTEImuNRwnS6/DjgKIQnLcNsKT471TWzHG6WYEBHiJAdiAu9GxWa7XY2gZIpS4lCbUbe3nqqGmJJ6ok2iofMbRCcb1ow2EqMS5Zkhwo2oJ4F8KHghBoJgIqMx2XK3ZeKxSDyOgcVYCzJbRe7ETjZwKNpkE6/itPkn/JGNPYmcjJeaHfiIYz7ihecrWUkCkdBdUGeTKSlNBv7Q5p6iUHf0IlHe40mIs4XEKw9HoFaHrsCVedp8va3tDd3WQign4oJCSoopuochgtJRhKJk33lViIG3ym/yS8qXZg@0wq49YrELzJXEYiZeWhtAG7ChgD4Lhv1@1xH75tg1LZfxchZLq7jYE0GMKQ2GcoAGODx@Fl1i8RESGewQIV@jHUcUEOA1xnT9JcP7tUC0th0AOTCUmjvmN3PiNrMSX1K02TDgF1nTfd0xJHjN8dYT3nZqKHLhlhe1zdu3OwAVCAru@fwaZ69dVpTfGzrW5c6XrFQorBcLy8UYyeRUdcFYXonfwhwGlArFQmG1uKIoO15/zE1HNEtHWCs5BJhlL7CjfwO8aV/h/VdKDXoMiohnRwa2f2W3DEU5tls0B9wcEkWQlfFCbDqlgvbRow/oVnieEF4RG2T5PbDAYfjE/pmfDWCR4XJWwTXavu33nAFfyfWu@E3gcl267eG95TQRjUvCnB6YqGcPgChLOkuiRPv@BS6ku9B2fKCGKa7pNJveFZ3TIcgAeqqDxxvRAquCm1QRQjwzfsdfDBPIz@qaTg/ZaQYCuIslooBEAIrWGlr2nTgohMRn4iDvH215Fl2wbsqayYP086itQHO3fQekb0RgqhVKFsMdKvj0@cEJOzncP31bO95j4D46PnxzsLu3y559w06f77Gdw6Nv6GRU9vzwBUiXE1Z7tQu@r06PD569Pj0ED7V2AilVClBqr75hez86Ot47OWGHx@zg5dGLA4AG4I9rr04P9k6y7ODVzovX0Fl/mWUAgb06PGUvDl4enEK008Ms5SqTKVE6drjPXu4d7zyH19qzgxcHp99QjvsHp68ws33IrcaOasenBzuvX9SO2dHr46PDkz2GBVN2D052XtQOXu7tGpA/5Mn23uy9OmUnz2svXkwU9PDtq71jRD5Rymd7gGXt2Ys9yonKuXtwvLdzigWKXDtAPEDwRZadHO3tHKBj70d7UJza8TdZAfRk7/deQyQIZLu1l7UvoXCKdg9VoF52Xh/vvUSkgRInr5@dnB6cvj7dY18eHu4SrU/2jt8c7OydVJjy4vCECPb6ZC/L8KoNyhpgALUgHNzPXp8cEN0OXp1Cn/H66PTg8JUOlfwWCANY1iDpLhH48BUvLRDp8PgbhIp0oArIsrfP98D/GGlK1KohFU6Aajun8WiQIRDxNF5M9mrvyxcHX@692tnD4EME8/bgZE@HCjs4wQgAE/N9W4NMX1OpsZ4AL@4EZlUk52apOtnBPqvtvjlAzEVs4ICTA8EtRLad54Lm0JbzyswltzsX8KZX@cRUyN2H8Owc7u6BxsdP5lMj/9fQ6WwkF@8SYdDRhIHwKlZBqa86b9nN4cU53s2NQ/MwGV/B7gUXWTzgUserUc6UOw61FgvllCCVOj9/UzuHce7J@bmefUjKBBr3pRC73O@KpYsydj2zRcP8xNxSnFDbj8VZOll@sEV8ruVxOPmgs3y@ZYtkaByCgOU0kTj0CYC1UDKS1YjpsliWtMScnCuiE8kmJ4vk8qYXwI/7KXrhfUPMA4Qzt1vI53EMS2jgyXIsxB8yoUPXxMlrZAfgtClLI7DtywutEM8Oh/xigkqXaSjuAIaBF5p@T/KmfTGRPDeZnpBFWx5SVuRxO/IYHH4xKr4JkjFRL4ZPJdP41B49dIkNZQRKoc6zIkMhYX2iPebJcf82nyvUK@FRLXTc2svajw7e4mCuUFqpTPg/D/1520KrPjw7EPq7OqVr0ON5g0eABubg8AtI4oz5kmo@H0sDWhnpk2FkPAuog5GunRb0qdhVd2zq1vEEIn4cQzw9dMa@M4pjD2L4y@Pay2ev9/dBciK2Kxur62sVRZxo5A9@lOXPbzAfPNOdqAta9LUDahoFxVrJDug9@1OHEcZOT8Taw4h4mresNPLEi2HDnclcR@Dnl/FpICxugCc4uXiImYqHMPkqv/p4QZH8OrNlCgbQEkXVsTR4vz1q@CaoSsQDFt@F3B1TrY3wB2GHzV828bBAgoEEi9m9/mAMnAuDC5J76r406KSxDZltYRRDlXzcN6UNEicMykyyckUbR3oTvB2rRdBrsaKxvVK1U0pAYmESC3kIHh1pCVkceYFswdzTAZ8fCX4D5zfi8EUMwqO0aoMTION@mDInD0fkc86iYQjIje0qVNHjx2FOWwwnUnWBFJ//Tx7NF28NhAo3aGATgKXlUUjnMIQmoZ@mdXbDORVPTUE4FcGx4h04d1ZxBJSKPHJGvMsT@hiHFR3YR17XYR6KjPKNjBKSM0Gm34keBP@/Ik1mwN@CASdAj6hFcthxh/YDKUlQOa1g9EpEca6lxVjMTC2iZtzrmwjMbbxiOmHBhBneiC8sAQlE7Yylxzf8yFZtBgGQyXFeI95@wzvVOyaMnJ5S233EV/p91@r1NXngqewqpuA2sqRzZaWJHL7ofAm/wGLZvcDz657SPlqSGTjgAinWHLMvApXDyBRJ5mCh80s06RG2cmJNJENRtvCInQqiacnGPxIWRlEv05Kht6CKzj9MNVwOwTMbEwJfroBIAUK2T/ECC7JBntuI6MxyoyU9zfIz0YvjQeQgAqlfZqdk/hyYbRozY1ckbJXRKBqzRDhftMSZmE17cI3dRZdDJxvtCBrTviAzccxEzEWGaoQUvroBVKdO9jrEnqYpkV9D7F@7ly5eZGHzKS4Zw0icsBnf4m6wlyYdttl9WLnVKPMMknU7mf@BS3brFl@vxKk5GrlDLjjS/yKIKAIa5zVql9APRVQyrUv0VCWPOtc5ZwQPyisnSi7PjIQxA50IPEvpv507IEBembCBZeqZG04ilXlHVv1Cqi/o4m03dH2DLjHPXIVCAXLggwazQg1ClFFvQiPN6dZG@CW2LaDxaRk0p@tro2kOe6bbNntOd0xWpx@8jpsP3GHQxyu/VVVNzgbiQStogg64D2z21nFb3nXAnkFzwImkk1evT46SE3@xma8dPvPF2FeQB3tGOStT4Nu4JyXw2gOoGrvCxuJuHT@a7qF5QjHTQtNaY/TAjT8@MRDk2ws14y9fvWZf2q7tgz54RDaX7IVj2S6ID1CmyAoz6HBJg9H3MfcTkTvbR92FZnYqzHZoUiec21NEBgJaFllLg6YICPvi2Gqcmx8Dq8fmBI3pAkflaslJpY7XF7stcNIUlU0@xdkedrMKno399uD0OQ7G@cCc5magW5NzfTiXyFWnHp@shcL4pjsYA1GUyckbQPu@uRuD0WYLgKjMJycN6np4/00Lp/26ARQVL0YSUoB6EGiqtnOFh/HSNNxD6ojsbMW0WUS3iti/muXHA0vRkag9Jaq9LJ7JbmTZ6iY7tZF32VHXtGCExU6GmHx5GfTAZ14wwKgva4wVSsViMVdcxina1yc1gxoCfuUJrYpy8PLo8PgUCCmOIJKMEfaZSHw6FJVbYwE5cng0KpT@PQpkGR8kZuk9EQ9VcHlOglrhKxZqWYW6t0yc7oUSBkl1mKZkcUre8@lgVtxtAyyUaI6Qa3CNwpcvjVBOMehZOhpW3ppOXUuIJ@2WpATvEbcu8FUX10PfU2LyAwFgj8gPUvk0MmiJY4WgTnp2L8TeGcje3eQRlMkzZUOC8blUYI50No1aElBPj8Np2WgjEeDpTL3gyvJBtphXwHJowiK3HAHPkGzSw9KYTafrQBsAvKyOhx0OF1eyImgKIn7irEI1Hp5liB0S4TLjNChoXS2vF0blWClKuNlO@PeDseWx1AUMs3GkFfRtu0UnUQ37/KglDDeglXeh5@Db8MrRGUxKqkB2kz4IGzzyDmTfsIt783EvZZPXuSJLA1wlt2@ednBYzwFBiU4G1EjxRFxtxgg7y3CdV6dqN4EhMK2OhJizkRJA9LO4KAVYQX0TQ5CL2CWL2326VN@T@ywxIR32GPSTAQiLr@rayQAJHssunFMROJNWQwQmtnBKZPg@JO5OzIElX7C8aHeKm9I0XkYo3FgPibnv4BHlfG7AYxce/mJkQ1KMrxHatEY4tTEULzUsArzJmMXpmBArPKAtFrM0A2ZuJszl2TBzAqZYrDxwr2hDHKYituCl4KdteCAfkRBR8b/0pOilbXtdjy8whaW/6HpNPBcTJAXkho9xNqrYuDeNwBKEjofyTZrJ8zy3ZJEE6mJvk9Rd2Ba0D3ubbckZi@0zl1eUCKjytkR7whj1XdScyIk/okWRU00cDopax8TpoIge9wXZjWBVAVL4qGUWtUy0xInHFzknk/QSSYoTSQRyySTNRJKSEu0En6hdTIGiH5/Jkkm9hKySqAZYNayggtIzR3x0U6ANfjRNg0dyJ3YclhqCQTBi3WLhnkGM3lCiIzASy/Y8D/lKJnhk8a0uqnSkaCF5ntRImu6RGKBYifAxHbPiaqJAuiADvYTHa@gSGVGuLUrixiRVWGAeoCSK7eNeLS2ei15mqb7JVw0xVoAdWzzrOtEAV@lV@FtimsggF0eWR8JjC4QoBMLT0RZ1GMryapFysKBEPTO9xQQc1KDC5TeZjPFuQNMS7UpK7hAmd07JbgCF/hwc5aTw/dUB6HXcF3uUmGg4QYUPj4kXSp49guEZrTETCOp/whlr4cnPjAilh0C@HuXckL1GshRzY092JbPixHqVkAp3RZbEDuk0N/L83oZIh3MIKO949BjpXuAksSCd7ILTAScZaSnOgDaTe5bDJVSSbDGhy9NmZwjgZJVL5LITpVJiR8WIEk52I0qi50wwiRZ7w2tw2Bf8oGAOSFcSqZD@8yoczR3jDXtuvCKPJ6p9HkeEsGS938UWYWRZ73exBY8cq/a72UKeFR2SltJP8kWiJjgJ0ChRjBhoTikug2TAKB5rNBGLEBo34mfF2F1tBrYxqSrmOpUpVSkkkTgaLpkHPUa8YlJiI3eCHYF49bA2GlFpoY@zLu1WeOKFKH04RNpWk10Cr83Jg56w0DIHqqOGjleShAlAYvNJMDFm7nHbTToxKM0HLDQGxVNRLzrJ3b0JsLJXKejTCqU8HSlCfmsm8rnpU6qiIVZ5@v6d0LpMYI0GT57fwtiqMmPFV7kHq0wMq2TpYjWUJPEcSLkHQco9AFI@Bkk07GXoL8mZ8vEcYPs@EGdn0zDo8Q4GUgIGSNqWg5PYOA6@Nsf3wVwAZStFNnUmtyoLE0R68n0wnkzCoHPXO@FqnPDsmDjr9tH2vclTz@ZSNskrMzAKsUpNo5VFtEhq03hXxJOqEo1tjctmxwlHAqn7a5qfEyESoylxJ1wESiVPLQqBRe2/OId@2Vi1JtsDRzwxDQPasvKZzcFAQvAZJr5VLEwQE2TJcagISBLi7tBJ4Uej1cnTJfBA@bnJ9HtL8pRP@MQmnYpQNC6xEhwnh3CRcJK9lZRvs4Zn9@afmpl/3@uDjtOeiQDF7@E8Pp@UmhDpkWo6MbR@UF82sz@bLldcb5s4@@3hjfzxVNFLUHTcmA6N2rWvRe9/F2RRFlkDv4UmX5c8MgfJL2YiiQvtppjcYu6w17R95SFNnacw8MHHSPM5V1FSKVazYMgsTh6iG6DoeGRbZIlqMDJCwIZ9XK8JuHEnNm6cI7M5A0/GxRvWKbahYhY0R9uzTVccRSQ6zAsf1y/CuFk8Hh03d1EOjmsBoQM7Nv35nt/50bJFCFok30HWyuy6R66mG@A5FtkoJ4EW1zW1cXJMy33nKDihVkOxypOKiuQdXAxd4pq50JdAMddnT4E9RHu6SyECJp6XpRjwToC@m0fL84k57IekDKvmAaScpW6Fs9wPULfGD1W3/itQcrJClZhbaA@igy3fK9QmB/l04a08@Lo34@iWN6f7@4kDT5pjOSro2f5qoVDAQ3CmbrfDBQpcJXa8fDJ2HufE8/3rr/w3zTwmTd5nN/M6O8QBomJsXJpAPsGliSH0N7HjtHA@x8VdOR8CHpOfwNNiZMbphMbtb06J@QgkEs8us/dYQCzfeybvnAbFkQ8ZBBRpbwapUQ29UqWZHJAHPdp4ok5okkbAaNwsdi3gwkd1@0Z5JK54pHk@vI5Hv4m2IarP7W7Xy7K3nt9tLah8d2gywf5@PEGBR0FTQt54AroeIsvsK6cbuyIDoyBuXtc2ut4Fv2MJ78/ls5@0l8m3@7iSpmE/dmxf7I36mlp/pwJjQpEzWMwMUxu4vedChS5KpSX0@8HyA8kA7QfF7pl9zSI6TUaGPlDspYpcgNEyXqLJrYNxPmUHiozGHFoiis7PheE0uz82EnU2usYHz3E1KDoGK7hdjrZ@U/VSSeZED4mrno2KbaRhgcMQOOERiA9LcVvBQ6d@@w/ObuPMAW5upDnecEts7LyxeDnkZDy2LHY1aLehefGZ@G151JgER6IyVyQrBSSNqFjf/nYI@oyWbgdpfoAdmtqcjF0rgUi91Miy9HDQ3kgDhN@pjIpsgaL5AT3RbOLrHDTr/SHdkxLJM5qGQwOKabmDCc4xgaJ8YVW/vdZqtRpb7GcyrFZ7Bo5cjtWe1dguejx7xnbh/Rm@P66WVlcr3HJuV78Bz2fS85Y9AxjUBeGdbLvwCmF01RIOpbCKF/PVxWxl8by6tV0J8vXas0Y@fwGuv/uDn/zdP/3TfE28fI8vz@il/i6MZBhGftG6WXx8W8H3@m4jvdisL/Yb6YsKchmK@9d@YHbN2DYxw/oHuRdX7py3dAYarV6tpln60yfuOhtETj9y4iUGUXKz2@@YlJwRhO1qupZ@/BhcW9X0j9M6ntwh/M3Q/yP4Mx1lOa0XE2lp@bh2snNwEL8nKLx/tI2aJi64m8I4zXEDBwr1PiVXz3N1ZhiskWPvQ/TQoPucR0yiyNJoMcqR@U4gKUuHmEkA1BzURg4N0qq5enFttZFLpVIqN1NzCDNun0oWSNwwipur9YILsj@SFkwURtZimOiLVpnb1hGMDEhEjF/hu1Y13h4fZAoHHU14pzi7YXTfrcqvcR3HrteLXa2LZ4hM3rsenlsb3bxOF69LgNbE2QaTALnpHYyXqU7QEpBh5Yp36MCnq@m9uP@Grci1GrGH3euOL7p4HSVtQwiuob0D3XVxRXLXlecMYg48ZdNu41IibyNEsdg2OFK1bNxd6lo4Xw8drdvFY2m5CiUvIgadDDgMdQZxskUbd1FrXZcb33ttcOp4aby8cJnqLUPHJVGd4LpIlw5d4elly1rqgzbY5zGRqvAeGa5iGchsWpg8PJo2YezrIiUtkeFuUmDWfh1t5IoNeTy@LlhP7fR6PZAnnMlCYxjQ13o4uMPpBiAOpjDoLFdodGP2vuu@n3UhM9n/UdY8uxK38QVZEGbniCVNyo5vp1V1Xio8@dU1B4LMfS8IHGECIqqL7Fv4/lsfoJ6lFZ6Z4Jr4ldVLfSpoKsq4y1snZyl7BPyOM0z8NA/IHQopuCEREc0i0aaPW5ylEpaudG85CrOmPXAsvgmJ574gpVyfDtpAX34iydyMQC3nhpayoimHMyb2dwobS6ryCA7RCff7smBodUKl1iSaSeMdjq88D6VfD5kkrJ2ziEgRxJATCECSKAJHmvYRFHyUYNCufeEMEmmyfDuz2LnJS3ErSY@N/T3ZEsaoO0FZtLqRd0aHouG9oLc0b@6DOJJhICk3uN3ybN6ThcH@gls5hSl5kehIio1p/gjlkkQnjjW0ZCAfNuNssoao28JexAk4H/M6iViVRbVwZw4EXKDI5cYS7ZEnAEJqTNIkV8ebcyeoAWJ1ohlE0riQAB9jYGTueB9JsmqCvLy6eGc7JcQlv0hMb2fcBP@PmW@iKps@HuIKjQ9iIR@AKhCZaTchhmtFekMIcmYLvLalCoxi2KGdQf6wCzo1N/8WPUv8svUo0xCPiaxk0UUN50gH6cujwOrpeF1OJJXljVI3kqlzaX4qwo08GyHOMVyjFqKChnB82lYcpCDSPOJdPfS1Mjd@FIJWkK@38swGceRBaAku60xUBHW@ZhuJhrblKOOjKrudxTByzCxlv6SE0DvQFCUOnGDRWT8iXty@fgbpbpX/Dw)

I am using [version 3.10](https://github.com/trizen/sidef/releases/tag/3.10).

Sidef uses the same [embedded comment](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Embedded_Comments) `` #`< .. > `` as Perl 6,
it starts on line 7 and ends on line 200. The difference is that Sidef does not count escaped angle brackets.
There are currently no `\<` and 3 `\>` inside Perl 6 comment, so three more `>` needed to close the comment in Sidef:

```
>>>say 170-3
```

`167` → `170-3` for YABALL.

Angle brackets were not locally balanced which made it harder to understand what is going on, so I balanced them on lines 18, 28 and 196.

Perl 6: `27.say` → `say 27` for DOBELA.

Answer (score 6):

## 171. [Agena](http://agena.sourceforge.net/) 2.9.2, 8955 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796lo
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>data B=B Integer--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W<p
>instance Eq B where{-[ppWWWWWWWWWWWWay Uce stagehere]-}(B a  )==  (B b)=a==b
>instance Num B where{ fromInteger=B;negate  ( B a             )=B$a+1}
>main=print$last$169+1:[128|B 2==head  [(-1 )::B]]--}


#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#   print(171)#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcyNJkhj4uVL3D@5LMMEqZBJA4sE3QLAKfHWxu6rIIVlV3QOiWIlEAshiIhOdCZBAsdi2qzsb7UN2J82O1kazp@2ZPZ3dmp0@rEk6M8l2zc7s9FW2P6L349rZzT@Yc/eIfOFBsmZ2TQcSyMh4eHh4eHh4RHhENHW/@5vfpPDDjl173LHdARuY/oC1POvK9DS2M2bPdMtfLS1LEsaqeZ1hz3QGfllKsSJjlmNYLXhnA/fSdKyPpgf@Jcb6ntvx9B4bdPUBM31D75s@c4eD/nDA3PbsZMuM7ffcD1YOU/YspwPRBqbX98wBha8w9tqx9V6zpU@ErE5k2Pcg3Gd7pv2p92nADLfX052WDzHXGHvper6J8Q3T911Mvs7YaN80JoBuQFTds9wXtVdfTARtMvYFoKj3bXPE9KY/8HRjYLkO0qTATl@9Pj2eSFEssjdnBweTviX2Vc512MHQuJwMWmavPV@39Un4K6w2HLiHg4Q/1c2x57aGBtJt0DUBHNK6bdmmLxlAk23WFzWsoYOlmGfqLR5NarsewySsd2kzixn9PmvaelczmG1B3IPCBjOxathHCLe7Phv1e8y3egDFd3tmHHefOabZYn7fNKy2ZRAGzBwNTMcHTH2NWVDWa8u2Wcu0IUGElpEFYGzox7w4EprUciUGH6M/UYjwbdGEOI4ZEMLsQ80hIVysaKBKQI9rT@/3AUmg5CkgPrB6wJfWIO0zU/ct5HxI4ptOi2jYD9uEy3QnXkp2ZUHNAL5Dj2D7pocVoRFc1jU9E0DqIVcq1541ABIgiWvs2NQ9duaZpppsH4ksITMXcxhgQTSqwq2t9P7RQRqqkqfQ9P5ASnnLZz/6UtKZVmWLFxX4VmW5Iu2/2mM3i@fo5s0BqrvvKbrKqt8xP39@bsJ3VGzmO96tBFAloIrN8m5/kNdzfUAwNwAE8zo60ZW7Kml9O5Yx25qoixiD8VgtqA126LA3WSqZMfQ8bPIRUfVLKLTtOh2gJxTWGzpID4etFaAKDBdabJaZV0A1aCJUR@41Ufisa0Gl@VglsUbABRcRFEQX8J6gaJCv79pDigcp/QEyIFAFkiLEwzZ7w9q6ZWMSCEdQHGvP9If2ANMMnRbWPAgms6WxAA3DbWGknnsF2ekAlDygPfVirZCQgshQES4VFYN@@Bd/1up0AE7NMFyvJdj1DWu5BolYnZAFucWQYV1HtwktiJfF3HlyyOBKt62WPsDsnbHIgpCgXK/dod1iLmToXVvQtLr6FTTHdts0BiZnci6Vs6ynX3LZYXHOhYL39CZULGVAeVOxc@zZLtSSYUop4plcbzhob7Bcf5@l/fw75WlZebpwbgJyqqYuLebznQownLZEXvCWvotz3tQS0s4f6L5rtaT@eNB1nRLLGUw2qm7fdJR0AkY6m/aaaVVDmaaoFatqaG3LaSnpLeDFbcg4rVaMqlG3yo3KRPJ4lgDmGsFgczUVQ5UlEDnUKK7yPd1ytP6YvckJVyzM9S@Q5BisxbyRMJN@V9wjRb0S8qWLDAJySPNt0@wrBa2oopjAeDPLjQGzSjoBQxS4bDUy6VQ6Ey86QYCSJgqKjfXMclFs2f0udkhAFMfvg/j2kHcNHbjHRyk@ANUgy5rE1yT6QbKQTLw2057JmiBIAz6iJsmbHKbPoaAUEKImlGzJZivWkEEIQFse@FPS2HavIUPCCfsuEB0OZqp3oGogMS9IjReE50Q@ySJdOiBQEFrTZBu5pgWNAJsbyHTB87GyQfTlEo8D0Hgjicmenj4GKAbvC6MGw6w2tKUeiAdvzAwTZQ4IH5N3KJjJkNqfD8oQqkWFXGl1NdnGpprYwMvXcj8GIf0xf2dLwsLXEioC9Dxt85rZutMZ6h3UxxxIohuG2R8IQQUl8Qcgiib7G/LMic5T87vS4rPJvKkTEd1qLA8U8rz2RFeoo3QRGlnOBmHKdKFTspblgViyx5O5Q4Sriczl9xglgcB7eQ4KgQYATGaOTGM4AKkGDHzdtYwu8Cxi53C5yDuhyezBK547SPZcO8wakSluPylJWj70QjTmgshhjU7Dgc4VQW0nPKjy4x53Q9b93gzAbogidAQxXy2va8B798DsuY47AygQMgSLUZIhvB5AEztFLRA6rkDtosYaqoZhFUGdgdSAlg/81x0M@n4Z@glr0B02NeCU/Jk3PhwcOcgs@YE3tgYudzdttwli2Yf2mQ9yyBvDpjWaKBD5hXX4wZeuQAFr@6wKPfe3Q@A6Jd32QWCS/y5GjgXJJLgJBP@VISJF0oBQStsnUXwAQuV07BiKrFFT0qDRyVkmY8OVVXBgqpAuu24PpRB7S4oBano7HkiuNkgrIfNJ5Oszu7pQ9pNel05rH1zLUW7SCwsL6XJ6GyT7wsJTcG2h6ym6MuB6Sq4cuTCehi5KkSUXhtYpBfo10rf1APJIbWC1jbBX@mj1Fb1eLi83snq9KJ4lfKog6kCyQewcPgBOWq1W0amq8vY1FFRrtpOl30XpfGp4Vl8Q4Uv9SufvggrLRAar13c9VGAr2MneTZNe1YNeEJRWo6t46fN64bxxfnPeypzfprOYWq3o1SYUCvJTelrHc4fQXar1lXKu2FDV@jJ0ks1qupBeUpSNnA0Z6ar6eEPN6JzaStoEqa2cn6eBqII@daPrEbxRtqSqIakAD@yYQSdU0trNBuTfVBtqJg1p1XQWhhjVdBooYyARfCo0ciYR6AAYcPf0RWJI2LsE8cgM30ZdIudxdQJe80vcs0WPUGUqs0NSOR3oLwEF6C5b4dDGcZ2cMyQFmLRTN54RDcIwBvlh54GC0UrEQcBtawQaPjTccaDJYAeMyswuDPNc29Tekm4hM@B8hu1Vm6nOHPN@QTP8qBJBcQFn39YNaJlJcOcyOweAwKj5/OwQtTIFeFLXoWHJfWWEnsHQHaRfyyK1e2j5XSQvqEY4FvDaQFXUuaFzN4lqh8yATrsDlDZH1oAr4cAIp5jkue4rKqp9Na42obaGXT4iFQzZqT92DRiwmND1Yygf/bF958ryXAeJrO0DaODYCtbBBPBZ5AU2qtUOS3vz6TsLOFBsyrsYo20c6iRxDd9gece13Y7LliACsqamccY@dAxAAZS2AYwPmW99JALVOi6MXJI8aGJ/7aOSV1xbDtVnHWPmKb72AYQFm13oKMKcMp8e/ngfRHxxtVAA/IO3An3CQsagTJYRPQ0WRRDNFpr@WXdoSqbRdZl8Dh1kaZvlW@ZVHpubDD1RFzS9HGhTpke6RJhMTFVJA3cISknLtK2eNTikuRnbwZ436lWC0F1grwjAsWUOJKEuR50xTtNEgtLp8Pj7I5SnvmTSk7062tu/OK6dPa/K@aHv5W2rCfXXMi96oDfZpi8zlmInJqQWCT5e2ieuO6hSleCM0PQnhZGC@C/2Ll4c7pzUTr7h2VA63@oNbR0z4/FP6T1gk9h0Uttze6GO6AvaLi4jNc3EdCEOmEToCoYOxWRhzH8N/Xs4AagZUscwWM7lr6GniLiOEXFSUDP6famTyWBMmiQMPUXMDQKJE4Wa1ww8N9EznCKMqeFxcLPC5ycSkG@KhVsE7jtDvx8r2U2xSP5Xg3Yb@5HQu0TelzkAAwpk6L1M3nyKMZFVQJapoJmRQ3grBI9PTc6ENxU0MzKv/zMQhi9cEHwvLJ/mi@MMIYU97LkkB2pCQhuQo5BSNFxnuavZ8wxyHBDxJnDTpYvaaeS6gDH1KkIJQfQu7emUbegj6CcRdQqp6RDeJnrNNv3MiFAWQ1ho4DiRilT5EqfhcJTtQo9tXlM0UsYJGFDLcvT8CT1QLZ@FT3KAkUCmabaH0JnlQVtC9z3RcpsbFLPdbFrzogJdEPXgOSOaN2zOIhsMDrpTY1CWIPxg6A1ssyWe//X3WlAB09XT1cfUgYeOC6Ab8UZ7bm2JpPhCP7NrluJ8GNqWTmQg130gDR2n/XQ7dMwGjbKY5XJd3ethPykqF5gTf6Ct38FnHHPPtIctM3jOzoRInBzp8tSO1aMSwRMVPVLc5ySfGKfz9KQq2a7eIihcobHMqLZ5vZgj3rXHlAAQpw/AMxhOs2j@GsaNgyH/xSnr@@rV6uN3NlXKSSYrrOrNopl3fb1pmXfwgadfDlturn/ZoUIjamvzuJ03Ihz95dq2fsmdF@icTQBeRM/qdGDUK57zol13QWHx@6Dy5K/pcQerBB0Ko15fvwumZ/PfeVGC1b3QMZ9Olk0/n8OQxCIGtBokLS4m5WJksiYIa@vNMY7bup/PWZgh9dQgeKpGJlNYxm4snISMlq36/fnpse@j9Jubs1PzFS4CYLjttmne15qhR7J6up0rtWLOucI5mFWIXDOikiadM2zdByYZCDKbV1At9HMX42InYyC7RK472DZCJ5hjnjddGaXpW4ZrW36ftyTxMk9KTk70RGBwHZN@oqT4Nk3fFgwXsAPPha7ZDd01BjhlOIePHiC4@GwdzofGGENz59HOcK/xO1d16LpXJv@d3Zl9nInVA0RQzibOsIwZyVvGfeyKi070M5uKlzOxGhj2TP8ye@m6Xtd0fFbSCsH0Bs7467bNpw/PDo/m87Rv2a4PIw38vYsWMKLwff47m5vjZLN0J0eTOHH37GQCqT7TxJh3TmXqdse11zY6eR1@5tb40GujZBfPh0q0UCIVi/dKpFDxcZ2ieM4V5Zfwfx8z0ESRhzPCMecd/egs8SVmEucXEIYHuMwzu3AHhQ1KqeX5sG9eBXhG91ofB8/foreYR92gt@iPSW0GvQ4TbG6AY@BxVfq3yW3l7txaD5NJU2DX7ytErHIvbRMkNP1OVSkrFYqfmaJYKDxcQrXtoTk0Z0qMo@YHE61r7pAVD0eqIIqxKKZA8kA8nAAJY30Ug8IHYY39N77dKWB024JGfq/2MlPe9UHX7uM4@hgcx@iYTthxhv1E5cZodzJ0Tu6mXLcftGy3lUASQz5XIm3cryMl1HHfpO881X2/58LQ1@2BzuA8oP4FUJpT4r8JwOQTQf5g4fybdyfcMguXjkBfBf0DatW69HM4ifcwwVOaN2anyJubMCpzzMEYf@dRe5Ygbbqu/Tm1A/K0ZaFaBsom2obdV0tTuo5YRWTR7ISPMx3N9rx5Cd7XiAEkUA8Hy3Mr@hiKNKDO4SG1PDVpeEevFZtCvG8cCT02Tf74nhG45@F7go27qG1o63cizNVRt2naOn@M1lbugrepLT9EJeoHei7NIuPMM59rjlY@UhMiqD8GYlmtnG90zZ5Jr3co@Xrrw9APHnMjjVz8zgjW8jTNOidd34I27@BvYl47phUNXMf08wPd65g4PLFxuUH4zpOzweztTOIe9vSOeXAvc0WzD2hiQst5MefseYgyX/U1INk9koSP/Fzn0hz7wXO2fjw2oD6HvTuhzWrnBk5y3tuwtfzMSet71D6n63adrtn1qHGEb/OaB3DkgJvW3lUIwL@r@5doU0MyKRrWdf04dW3Xth9CXZSJXEK67uz51300Ym1B0s@CO9abECAe907VQddNRKI@fF7b6ZpD6KF8d@D2zRy9zYtq46QO/509pXx4lPbZW8v0Wnw9EWf49IHVtE12bQEKH/z4utzsCaOm7epotnWHEg@UCZ4PmYIyXO@@XqGju4N@nx4XfXvo0w/N5Obas6coy@yAEH0IL1gDvpLLOdbsuE2ja91XeU1THzjWZV60fvE6m8uTspgKbrHcHnprtgWk8sYa8kA1Hn6Kj8PZ7d56IQzj79RHdoeeN75fNiRXKcNZVb4WgI558y9i9WlGMPX8aK4QLMvfsSAhFqvmMhTp0qg358wCKCfFubNBCdMKQQJ7eXlwD5UM17i8V52YOz8pFjaRVIYVW34F/8lJjLvReC7EGwwOlefDjq/eF3@Mqtae1eOm9rodGRXdk7LW4ZyDC0m@7V7HJppBJOiOeMzkvNKL@9sTrYas3rkwUmbFFxe1o8P7gRm21ff5L8u1SzNViOnFy1k5foNVeDdlTqEltB8@eOi5HtqhgraRMzzTN3ASHAU1F6BcPDluBwR2zmZR5CDuzLJML5zOUmOSnWHu61dmR0ezlhcWWrjY/qz@sdYxHZ2VQHEs3VVEviZ7Qtb5oR2nnxXbCsDP8oQRuR/u1EiRpQdZdQZWfiyFtqZDbBwD19MYxVMUPZNRVYknwmnGjgPRglhkK492tNwM32e25Q8ortVm9TpbvBmVC@XiLasyuSyzRoNDJYvO/VGfjNxPeNL6ot6oLqZzufRi@twps0Kaopq2b86OqifitS16cDyjojNH53Y86A5KWuH2wX6XbO@hI2lBh/QahjEklFyPW7lyE@ozXK/8L3/ZElsSQGn1Wc8C7gVC4DYat2d23eunPF@Re63f13FLA8K47mJvh7nndmvMv8aei@9EcK/Z64OzDWHfLDb7wMsxitgYFrxScQSFxk0DXmkcm5ZrcrYQGYepgkIZrj3sOaAqtAZdX4PWQnZLQy@y1wAXRnMGHupLrSw7ZC0TV4XIHI2GCLbrXpJhKGLyX/6SW3WTUZowFgqyp90csRzR9qxIptSG4Q4B6wDIR9NzRRQFiQztZogDcGBqk/uraKpF5ubAibnA2Bqz4QbXu7VTlttnadyNhCacFautLNZOvnhTLzSq37Fe3vyvv5dXbwTd5Me5zTVfzrIgSuUW@SoevArBUWiayYsjWRQL973QNo@QqcRGOQXdVF2B8XSPtswQ35nXZDxNJj8OigXciwKC3wcldaASaN5oqovKkA/1cqcDtopbtmD0pIOLb7IhUzQ0BMYkiyP2iXWRV3IGmkfBGyeIjbbnvepOsNq/HLfJyO@ZzSEtRF6VtNJylYqzeFHd2iaXZ7Zc3ANSf3c@KhVy56P1/UbeD4hzfj56XCh9DdRzQQtdfJLHBrT/au9mUdsufPrk62Mmy7fpCjc1gVa@eHN8eLx/elY7e30K1LzlhU0duF5PjyQF8gJZe3VdmzbXAFk8y/Tvlx6hBAnfILqisEWdbeH@PlWV4qZOFFWQWs7Ji9wZRoHhWDz1PclnpffNWPh0BCGZ2hYTUpQdEyMJnkn7cQmaDXgL6wWbOyjNIUXQkGeGKCQayawKVMoBlR5IIzZdSl6DT8kDqvF@Qt0NYxYIoFUUYzoCEinMC8vLw3nhZhb@9h@gxH3o137XEhOMO0uMMe4qMUSMklGKg9rhi9cn@8lEwE7RTkoY8nq42bZNbYvvyeLc5YrtP4FkotGiL8z9Q9nqsyvLp9Ek8lsbewYbhAs2R7JH8FG6cONgVrN9kOStFoim5niAkg1EukYWZtzMLOcwOQXE0sKONstkCeP61entICC5rg2QYu954kWKR5B9aca@tXMz/8O/@DO@V@18AO4/FO5RYQfe/li8tcH9z4OQYhHe/mX4VoK3n/K3d3kk5fQGHV6akIhIwDeHx8ynAS@SqKePYqXHvg37TsuBIZfVA1pfEekwOi9WRJkIjlJ/A5SH6gKyo5BGuUz5mV5Dwe0V5XweVRGcpdTICsoc8eEu7bb4doi7DKErya@trq0UYbxn5q4CgGQx3UGzGw5QVcvAldKV1a@@bxpsa2uLyb6h22Z1rcJJnl/U3y3L70NEFyGuxLWWOoM0kCRKAWHbIpmyqGeKKibFxpkuplmjAgoJr0Ho0xRyQBQVvZ3A6BY6TVeQCtjDMUcDEvzjQBsDVcghm0@T7zUNAOUAEIeNe@EmuTwypEG7wxjfa/FqkN9itFOMVpZnMVn9HTsfnDsNsSeSAcP8cgbLOeD@oxkbJUPuqU3v0FMm99dhadizU8dFg6sDwJYppXxpOV9cU2NtShagAF9sQZ8AJLQZaIOGaX1w@35td//wy6Pj06mdZhQzPRktzdLbW5nznJatN0JHeoLrA6LuHORPX@4cBKSMYxWtV2CMaNFiEs1ZuU1iOif3t9yCaTpvCpjKqFh4KGAadOcOaF1vGnoUmo9F3OUWFlO5KurNbb2xtX3upKay/zRr921KW0LmAte5T3tv02yGzDkM7LLO8PgFXwvMeEtytLc8NNzl75H3/L1i4WEO0YaxwAJMIlv40BRe0ubYhkHZtTzPinZLccQCfEHWBKgWEdUoQ0OaWnOKY8NEWabPnRA2zCGRjvhAljbB6g6MYTzL4LF9EtB8uEs7N2HAcziIxkgw7sKJFhoKjmnYA6IinOppWTR2173AYjsMOTV7Vu4swAcFR7QBTOx8grF917aaFb1aH7HQ/PmufVCa37etgYKbskYaDiehNIqKBShu4a6mkbq12RAbyFiwzytDW8WOh0CvY7fPoiH8nhm4TmAUx/aGABzYwGRfDnsQr02PExN7CZO9cnOQGOiYDpCo4@YoUQat11qF3LWuOWpZHehpFDULIulxsRhtMtNxl5STBjnMSfUFGuLECfNZG@NiFNPrumY5LXOk4H6OcgOpA/7p67dXaVWe4gHanSc2q7Umt@kFwkIfiFYbbXGbEAibm6EgSLadzU2t60tong4jEMjxdOC9ACf0oUq7p/eZMqR9jj7TGL0q54qT9QeeynLb2J9dM4dlMjR2gQcFaIxStsll2TjbreCxAEq@CvWMvr7TwsdHq8/qRU1rgJsyUdkizj7sgrqB43ZVAtUUkpQJLHTA8FdGjK5hlIYY8eciZSvRTiWINTOYGnKnSw0QaEGlZttPoo0xsRbIqbq5WRa1kRSHmwzYYmuGxACwM8RcoJsCfYWBMVANhRjE2oVBqQUC5dlXpuNAe1WAZ3rQOpk@BCbz1Gxw7k02Ou6AckhxFJ8Li2VANHkMwn76xnZBn1nMV2gEXLmFfv/9OXb8bdH1j/P/fV7LV26URbs6zoMypm4ri91qMbO8lMksOkvKooPqyJMnOHC@XQRt50KTNXkEkXKLtloBfgbtqLroVBb1LWWxVS0tUQp4zWTUG0jwnZ/Xbhb12/ziE9AmsuDj8dapLPq0Q7GgacVbwA9byGI@Czxzgzv16DQbzH7RymQQB23xAhH4Ln9@mqF@5fw0T2P0ilBy851eIEaSukpYE1On8HACCu9yKNFXUaKLVemLIHL8EIQZYXdq11@hDQ@j9QbT9@P8lQx5uGARAg2FkxAyCt8iCgQcKUBEfM3qqgrC5De/SRXXYNT3dG1ZcTNPVwuVTHq1WEmnWOqZnF@SPfnmfC93xcxcut7WV7VvG8eXx8dfq@cK22Tp1O6RXFyR37HN0lJeSuWXCp/W8/n379@DOszq29q21lDruXSjrvAB3TrbXl9fyq5tLGWfpS@iEeQ6U5VSSYVKO2er7Hxd15cyK6VnTgVCNvGzzIrgxN8N@BbZ6irbx8/f/se//fnf/oz@fk7fv7Ysq@@3WvB1u@ySfYTPZZvhP7k/tmJuHd3N9kcFxhmgflapaRSP0@nV5fTpO9yL/HQB/ugfPuEr/i6Qj/CmKNOfBSm1baQ@porFYmpMfxfoLo5ig@ccvYzmffLFYukcz1pYXlt4xoCqJghR/JTLz0IYeXl9Q3Zd8uhCDqvMTbHWUSyXUQ4/Uio4zSNX19sNNqjhHztr4t/JAP9yby7x78TAv51L/HvZxL/jU/zr@/j3oy79efj33MG/5rf49@Ij/p0Z@EfYb1SzDJD/rlrlSDOB/ORntremXQQuhPJ@6331d/uwz/n0pRQM@lLb241M7va2rr3LVCriH8RlJXzDD3cBvo3bXG7r3XYmUye869uiAFu5xjYvDf1qF@@2AGxmq761pV1sb4@2c41323Us5Q3@GP4tPkoyNMHzJXRWR1snHOReABPbBcM/@rzgudSPX8Ao5yxb2sqlSge13Wzp9PVOqghvq9ErBi7j68l@be/oNcQ@frFfO93/4vDN/utj8PcbF9vPnmU04JlngPB2oy6lRo8z25nqYDC4@PHFkoYd5CbvJzdDHCY@FzNc/FVK7W2PXudzW4D0i4tNLOAJ5ZYDajQ@MQ5WStVTdSXzNPO0YBeuCsXL4uVL9yj6PzoaQYA1KnxwvUK30C22oG2xgvm6MC6MR4Wee1RsgdOEv0IPnFahPSp0Ck7BKRbHowSo@f@9I3fw8sgFaC6kHIwKAwQMkFaO1o6eMXjtHB29BLBtQOED/FmFQmEEuI4KV/BfsIv0eXdRgIKruHMX3gqF83OpzuT3JshKrZjWCmltLZ22Gqtr/W/Pb25La9/WSbdb3WzUcZd2Q2bZ9MV5Pd2opPL@@Xmey3W5tCJXaBv37e3FxV7trHZxkccpsdHWYuZZJvcMPtXtzJZ4PE21titPz8s5ZMKAHVP5rafn28s5dK9loApK4LeVz3zmJwIJz@2FcymtXL99@xa/b6@vrrmLHNzv/G0Yij9v8@DFXegFH4yan5U@6RhN852i1FcbN7fQv52nK2nRAyqMjkSQi@ejUpuVZBxlKJsqKBnFZVRl11aZur29tgoeaxtqTingKIQnOZf7/f65rNG8i0bGq9VqzfP0MY61lBUAomyuVqvnsu5dnMv1UgPTruY215jr5TaXVVlV3xW3tiAPzKKkgrecHsmul2Y3t/E/5eZ2S6GPin@qip4q8A09t1UFIqir8Da6UdiWsqWgH3hhupvbbXRSvBtw1RW1od7ecj/4VdQtDnVbBcIxUDD@kf6h4/n/z//L18wHPeU2hZqzw1ZWVaU5NtWVNWUjsyn@qgtAWEVeTi@jSpTW0/X6s6XlpfWV@tPGkraEX2XrfLsxo3tWQVGCphy0vWoxhRWL8kyrnMjFkpxGdypVMcQhELbbYcubFezRMaEMH3RJaQYVur0VsnDUc6vbWP@MapSpDabe3gBb80DQrhWxQHV@PioUgkQqqzSrizcp/baSwlzYrRwkES2E8lDSFVrFlG/kRd2rFxvyrbx407zFochSUSUtdHWlUlla4e5FRSlurpU2S6X1tbWN4voGKCdrhUKeFYsbpZWN5dXNlZW1jdU1kG@qWqEMl4pLAk4B4AjnRqVi@rpRQcFVSQEeigKDPiB@6lyqNs0OZA8E6sfbdGZ1dXUhX4LH6PHafmm0sLVEn@2lmZ@N0kZmKfOsvrS5iZXYIM9PC1IFFxX5Cqack7loYBubhEkKlz/4usPiMagk4m9pb4m7ivjdX/ClPnNgULteYC3Xxi2Ibru9AJ5d3WdN04TRm2nbwSkjMMC0W9dWy1yQ6r1Ru0HbvKu5enFttZEDxvgwajNiBsk34dM71s2haV4Ph9dm@Nm1fP3DB71Pn1H7h1/@5Idf/o8//OqnP/zqJz/86ue//v7nP4HvX8L3p/z503@3uYq/v/7@X/5vP/z5r8Dzr@H7n@H7n379/b/@Pf6l97@B7/8V8/sb8Y3F418JYP3xr7//2V/8@vt//gv4/hvx/cXk94c//ff8//8Wf@j81Q9/@jf4I15@8lMo7t//1S/x/2d/9ff/@Zf4/7//r3//V//q7//435Ljz7jj//k3/47//t3v/@Tv/umf/N3vfz/n9yd3/n7/AP/v/xF8Ho7nQ@A8pFyf6/P9b4XP70KNKBfgAeC0P/rhX/8B8Oqf8rd/Bm/wHwb9YfiSCOEvfxi9AIT/ZUaiP/r193/yF@HbHyQjJsIAyB9C2J8nwv7wh1/@3g9/8T/88Ms/@@GXf4ytNLeyma1lc8W7Bw4piLj6gHgYce0h8SAij7LAFqQSPfFHeLIFco2WpNVlHF/l@CfDPT8tosLJzj9Jq/Ce@ZTH42NY/pMIPce9QkUIXV6h0ALozwUMXcXXIDSGCi5YP32WUOs5IkufQBkGzTYfi80jPuWICv/Mp4RYx5QUvhAiDt8os4Uw/cIMwjxlzyAYek3qOLfwF1/AZwcGe2LMV93eYFUpyzaqbJvtYMQqvFM4Oukd@lg8Sbkq7bEdHKWi9x5QiA/N2Uh6j2PvDEXf5lHZtgTh34HHDgdD0BDUdxJ4ZbjPHjy/E/FHEsHDf6G1ohu/QQD8ZBj3g1fsdQiO@JF4DB7MgkecmjjCxniYboT/LAIk4GQkIEQmGx@ThVlkIi8pfM1M5RLiMxGWicKY6DwToDJsCuBdgQlvaTIhmwlFYDA3dKKYQeiMHIPQ1HSSMChOoEwmSTBMmSxURsqgadySyHQps0SWMEuf@xE4UQYzyXHHJ07vpajkcbgR9hFUwpcnyFDcKG@CqHCdipYSWHFtJQSsSgodMgYaKU5rmH1Q6qSXfmfHHSmFrCxni2uz5w5UnASBuN@45XL1u@LKugRPeh/ieWfi5C3gbTzEWtuCD@Ahbd/kUAhI26f7ZxB2dsSKpYLG6oXGzcp6aWV1ZbW0vLa2ul4qrqxtrqytbiwXioW1wmqpVATVdXNjc/1W2v6ajTR2fPyjHLhHuVy@hABZtbi6XhlXISF5SdukyHEFcnyTA90RETgn7fUG7RZwBueGZvcewYdJjyT2CLzgA4Bx@paJZbPDo4pYXEETu1BF5ystcnF1UyaNPpfzpXPTaXHgUj/2kc7w@NJXAAyo4bAXaHE3cNmZ69KhbTumMSfGbpcfQL7rub7/O8TZ0Z1LHrRn4dkpxiAMeq7jDmq/Zw26c2K87vfQntf0/tEg7PeagCBOfPIIO/Dj2a47K8I6e308p5QvQ0toXJchU2iIfnL4xfOz2PNsv7b7XFpjO0ev9iYeqyLSKnuxf3AWvq7z0CDpagjim/0XLyZfxQPHMQtsdT2b1TQNfvCZpQ89tcV3QZSiNl@vkNcKpXW5mL0YmzCYucnlbjtW0yyuwch1RX6SgjEUHn53yo/3GzgtNmoT22@uF9c312xXeokWKptFblps@WhDCYCuHTJhbeK5wcP@fE94oBc6PavTBeFx7YYRfN@/vg6ni94Gc0PhHNFb1tR1/H7uB3Iw45/B3R4Dngf5TYXY09Gl5zA47OH5eLhVaYDrIlabFSQNJUWptLmxurG5XNrIbmxurKzCMHA1WyxlYSy9vlnIFgvFjSKMoDeL2Y2VzeUVkEkQurq5LqWg5VvtfB4kb1GW6Wk5Bh6UtIUnTrlad1tKtcw2siobKS2VpVqhx3CDycsb5wUGCWUJzd6WRlW5tIIGgctFVpQlWWcGSx0c7BYODmR5B19wqnK3IMstfFndKBTWd2TZpJBdkJslSNTFt/01nNOUZQtfdmsHBwjhA76UNhCGLF/yEP5iBy/rEM3Bl@VlBMBk@dsQXAGAuxyjDUo14C@Fws6uLA85ehvwB/Fq/G2FkN3HFwzARAc8ZBfCZPmLIBGov7J8wuOJrJ4H5a3VZPmQv9RqCOJLKvwqL9RX@FKjDyTy4A04V5Y74Oh4MPCX5SY4kX9l2QCXMdbBrwcu3JzpDHRZHvNyYElkeUSxdeNSli8Cf8gH8Hn@XO8OWmaHf8YefxoQdAhB1mi4f9D84otmp9P0xrX9L04o6Msvn@sfxkOv2WmKhM0L@LiYCoIue@PJj4lBFxe6PTvoKwhyJoIuxhcmYXihfwuYiU8HM@pdfIlBX0LQrJUsARA@PYjcxM9OD547epMHBR8Koueo2ZQryLLYdNoKMa6epQcdx6jeMDRI8BX9KUmsMkortw2axXBDza0@HW7Ia@tyeQme8lN5GZzQNFghXWBMTp/LslrfbDyV11flcvrp01z6SfEpk9c35bK8vg59rlq5RWGnqDdtZZQdVQvgkc9vYYPGJghP0AJa@kCHwcZOYMKYy71NfLa23m71pW3asIK7Dva/hbHBNSotN7l6vx@Pqo/Za4gBETsmRmjkbpUdpgMiOFABZ1Ot6tVqMwbt1bAXgqMTKAUW1Z2KgztrTFTNCEZctaruoNHibVyFWbR1f7AIylimWK4XSxufdlipWiULe1ZXYISqlss7jQZ0ELjPRhSfy7VQMoGGAn0Rg28uJ2F4vyrqQ2YKnnmLi2q0Bq@k0@uldFpNVyDtggyUFoSmdTes0KA@ZJCIUB@bJUjumYMh9MaFyu1Uzt5lGSjioREG5VBm8hqoTeCNBwlPf57BoDtbXmqubm3/k6nPf/dPZn1m@@JH4krgWlFK3UotPPZpZVNK3Ui3N7db20GOX7HxWM8EA1v2hLFOZlFaTGPB08vJkVytWuuc1IL52tqulMotuytuanFxUUptnW3Ly/KRdhEu0WznaenvHNcFcQ1NO7/YWsj8Vus3OW37WbDsCajnJc/EHQktvJ@FL6NsrGJFdJifyvyWH8hEqgJMqYJz33IKZYNhu0Ncw9465wXa@i5Fyyzs@KY9dMgkrfwSdWRFL3NtpN4ARv7ulWXfbCzntsmSQgEOu70lrjCOaJlbSjmucAIhYXQyMEcDBVTqVVkMMUzWP918t/5u493L10evjw7Ys0J5owzD9XPgkWwxXUxDFT6DLtg62ZdS/U/uavE758tKqtxPL6@kl8MqO6@mOH3AjUyv1OvFBqsvNxp1YLQGU@G1Wi09La5uZFbKxXWmprZxy0hpHSmNruJ6IbecaggwK@squGm2vFRMbedTQdtRiutFNeVLqY2X73EmJbg4xCqRK59nbPF26xb@t29ZfWvrFodG@HsrnhDGw@kfcQ9e6BF9EvGiOFH4b8di2kWq8V1ui/9v4c/uES@ZvLYqq6n31W2o@HcX7y5SUmqTySWqq0xeDHWg3XRQzVpy6M/03y358Bd5LIHeuBS@mVtLPlvdLsLw1VzK5/Pn6o9KoINtbq5trKWk3wC57jA3hdDQ/qptwhAEpO0MA6yaZ73U0TjNCY2wwPFy@BFPiH4W3A0TqGsM9TW0MESFLe4ndLiYF12plPQb@3ncDoO@koQui@4DY21iOlxkGtC2BraE28tx158q3UiPANbQGNBOGvipSNIj3NKBr0oQL8ue@AMV58QKqvTokRC2/kDzBxcIHBMJz1yxIkE/AOTRWy2f0RntuDbKtwrquEHC7fNzWOwx44l8ahZc96RdfphvDOEl1uZYQGmWGOVImGPhePaPeLTmsI2oHBy@2Ic0MGhukymUSC17TbzBgIq30FZZ2GcADfAY76qgFEXHiAAOPLlqofZwP6KhUMwMK2J4m0yqIFaWFbOESZa1RcI6vjYgOYJvgwzzATDPXeElYEsXIltRBoEPFQJIiKWjrg8dutcxsqL28IzSekNlN8GuJwVD2RYrRduyBCyoDH7rGCU0ei1xGns1IjNBKzayULUVvntGCeMJn4hQt9LSINur8KrqV6SvFAM0INdTKt/1njwx3vXrvUZF7VUH@MxketAdXyoWj7I0qPaqwB79utWoDOqZjNWo9tSvFHzHSw@w7xZ6nK@KskHJnSrggiZqvpr9WHdy3zmN7EHdyQDKw@zSj6sfs3q1gBpY1qoWs3b222pRlAPyHFQ/ZpyKvgVfNCtM7EwCDSSjVxJemORSsasf63oDVTobEmYyB1AYwNOv25lMQ4XMbQicTlixnzzRM/b2qGLncirGerf89KA@AEcjU8X3sqJvjZ5@rA8hfVmBZxWysVVAHtIJWt@GuAN@FaAxr9MIdY4jaZwjQK9XrS79@OnSj5eqCwsf66Ncr5Hl5C8XIm5A5EeIfCW280tZ@rHKJkhCy8WK/NgqP9ZAOMpZK5MBImf7sZQcw6UfQ0g/kwmwvkV5SXchBSaryGFitxI/AJ1OPyYLdDqF3qfLHAYt3LcJaWu@YVkiOt9w27dg7K/jEQNZuulApxgYJi5nw8Dz0dOnUpC12CADOaNwaZqg3LqOSVf0eLhuTRf98dMU7pOvs8RwIHPDsTOdug@j9OW1WHMl0UQNzveMOkZBMXBTuK1wicW3RYGwIekBcUh6YLwcShEkkpATImZVBEJtBRUEqVBOtPlJIHTmAcon1KPDlg8ihKMBjXkGGlb2Q5VkE/CTBS5mbVF@4ICmIj2CQiAOWAarwbZBkLEnT5h43aqyYmkd@wKMhvE@ZIoYaQpTyPwBmAIMxPID8CjKQ8oEcHuEIbjtL5HRyu@Wkdi1q0CCzIcs37yr0eZdZej4fM860k3laGBdPHr0IVNdEQjBPw1DID2E3f4mJbr7Mts9enn8@mz/5GXtFH5h0LkRv8wkuChs6pqgPl7/07Qc2rpm6CdF85svDRic4bALjzLGewBb7MvXL1ip9GoviwcRAulTfJobOtRyCMn06aB3X3O9Tv7aurTyydtI8co22iVHd5/mgltPEB3qnO1oJ320kd7HCTzozMXpaYkLRnqm74vbj3LBTZJ0dg2dKdDDrfHQCsVtSbQBIbChJot9tJXI0j4Qz@pYdD1glwNIpKd7IwY8ObUPCW85otE1cLS0uVEolFkhi45i4CgFjuXAsRI4VgPHWuBYDxwbgWNTOIoB5CKHDMPf5eW1yLkeOTci52boXClEzgjCSilyLkfOlci5Gjmj3FbC3NY2CC5LBdSkpmt6GFZc2QjCaCpgQJ6rAKY46bkCiJamYkLylSlPyG8j6bm@WRAZHeaPMFKptBa9g/QJ4lYVjlWW45HlOfM34Ql9lcQHdcSw@54HUml/hNe6AdOpZYY7gyUJDzIxbFMHZcAcgJZSPQD@N9UyPzHDG5ej3cEIoVoM3yE53ioCaYp0MyFnnxnBpVnBHFppJjR@5AgLCRPbWi2Q5FiWEz0th7iS8ItDXUABixSdE6PEY2AdJPdiB3meecOZWS7fnWUC4Mwsp5DicFdnpULaKAS8GiSl/p@gVYP8uJ5iUm2DGiDuoSUemKhQPDqlelMsy7/@/hf/B/v19z/7Ffvhz3/1//6n/xnd/x5//gPoLKwURvjpzxhZdcDPv2Jkw0H2JFEiir9cln/4xS/h9X/6t@yHn/yMB/3JX8jZlRAQhKBXlPLn/wx//gB//k85uxpG/Pkf8YiYRM7eSgnVSoFYP/1rxiA3hBIC@8VfMiZnQMFQBOfVeRtvxA5a4ABCMtTJ1ZgM5794mxfQuKBmZIAr3orRWwYrQI0B93S8WDVqe6DO8PVHlNKGbnRxM73wcn3UfwxUYVxf6wC/XbdA6RGTE2ko/e@zMktnMA5Oo@CJMVUuw0X5RbnlKBTjZuQ8YIc3AglQdNdZiAkMbyXgbxoJjH0Nhy00Ii1yHhH0fYUXNwcdiBxwFl39JIm8gtQ4CSOuwaS7wIKhLjItdkP8xBW6AksSu72LsQwT4mai2iCXSR8YMkZnMMSTkofZ60OVQLKQ3khYfCEqZCfBRTUnms3@0cFEg8FPE1TMy7hECjOqMlm@Jy5SWsRXUeNaTsbn@IoI9UJ5uZE40WFWZPnrr7@WpZhfAXnIaykEIVYoLjLCoGIyqBQLKsWCAGcOk2TNaqk0gQN1HCgXk6eX8GQxEZVMFjEXtpygHhANGAvy6c9s2x763eo0aJLISWE3DTwGstioinZy7pDM2WayOpUAYCbTVCfrcjbowlSc6YqanRKpnfBJ1NZ8SIk0sUZB1JMmqRTWXHFzVs0lM7wDdLGReWBGpcLvmFHugRmtrd6f0WS1YtoE@Pn0vV/sBGIilPARMN7wU4kOCrvGXwDrReIIMfbIqagw5KmJIU/z2mXKjPtOwT8fnDycuOTUi51HjIOYV@7A5NMDz/ouDDlc1IJjdyq/FtETww5@GXnHcT3Tj5/UYvG97E4azwoy3I4DvVoWT0C2xA2@aFHAT4VL9ithzya00F1@4TqC5oRCzfPiwnKswcUFKJ92W40IiK@agRuM0xLe1A6uWHolVG2P@oqLJ7kP1Pthkr7Lk51ZxqVy1BeBacikxmBAZ5g2DL5YF@9y9F1OEiwiv90RNNLmQKHjFrtuz@2YjovHJGHqCfCHEWxESO/3CZcs07PMiGEkBtGKkdVVkfSrz07KvirhbaRB@lISQIIYWeZN0hgp683I7mJudjxZkN/p5@N7Gsf39G5825bnDyZxJk@c7cHn52W9rEQQIGKExvL9aGTFyWhT6CRQCb3xHmGe4MEotsjIqYWY1iBqTUTX2sAf2fDNp63EAvE38@h/dwUGyfcfWn2kzJ6OQd706NpPGqL5wcK4AtEPVTWyUoxlF7L23gPzEgMdGuFlmUyCy8F96tAw@33TwZsn@ScAfA/Po6nTFN@T/VOVB87AybvKssvS/Crau2iZtj42W4qImY3BDUp8YuotklcPKzgKOhJ6Lr88WilkiwlVjM4ToUjlOSyjZ69UdT5b8ShWyD20GEcYHs6nH03cTYpmnASt8jUQ1wMJmqIjB@mgx/64P@ZnENl0OFggR3n/w2vyFR7NdC9BgA78ctViNspWvUt8nihhkR7QI4RxtWSRaSd/0G25oI1P1eHnkej@ktIsQ5ioGtRyQjuZV@PWXTUe44qAJ7lW8jCWvI/pHsxzMVbjwCIRtvt5XcgU5F3dtg1DiUPkPnfWmOtMyQT0wxpznTm9ysUMgRqmJEk3wJvnqly/UCULnIfwvILnG3giQBiDXnCGCsqGem0w5UUhPb0f01qET91AXTRGRTW@jhiLJQVunMi9DfM05uZpTOVpJPIMW0Ayy1gkyUhkKWoBq@euKrDN9mCOdMYgHLnD4y6xDR/H1T1ce71JW@mylWXpq3QZBHLaTJf3FRDK6Va6vEcOP10@JcdluvwVOKK2lf6ULgfNAiN48EqOZ@gvRDi@G@nyrqLeSgM8bzXIV0uXwzqFOE/5K1Hklk@vNsWqvxvOqpp4MzgqlVmGHOPDw8Vi1RtZ@hbgn6KKc3whcKHKSksUGQcgiU4j1mPwfKDb0PBud0@Z1X2Ug6kpMb8RzaFAeKYam1RBLhmSPEqn0klhxBHDUJp8hCcgiHKzPBsjVpwamd2HjsjdwjvZgdjJ/Il6GukDLYXC6xA5PoljR@mD@kqC4BX4MDwx8Tw8p9AJsiOM0BhAnYEWEvV9@o5CYV1PnAnLaz9eQ9NzBFiJuSAKryUCG5PpoMOhbkqZ9d1@kkkoFFf7rHga/IhGidw7kYykgmiZc4LJW5QMBUO88at3FSeWDlFLiCAMrBcavJWF/QLJYgyKZF1MU@WND1CIyZwWHdJmItvuCSfF4@ImS33FvG4oSMuzJMmVFJOQWMNzDYb6gOcercvgaQefN3wNUo7w/HYFAcRShrlw@ep@hv7ucv09UKgDIkxkMEuxnt2VTqvXd/ayE5jbUbbTFYiBWbanzlSOwhwiksPoIKaZ38VrUyo@XlLMlXyeaQh9QtsPyBaOCe6h2@TYgsNCLcG7Snpe4sTsZWk@oaY1EvtKC5QWDXMScHjBQ0yjot2NKy/4rCrGEOyj4fHZFewlKzheeQiPCuBNkJy3cm/okHlV1LbpqK1o5YKvOrhoJRaecBzzBHFP9muhiRZ4HF2c7B29evENdLrr6@vq9FIEtlpIG/Xj0p3LBOGwpZTFQyrxXG2ynei63mDh3JGnTcrIA5QBndZtOPuJNq4KWRaT5xNtF9LxuDGKCliXUTPQE1IJVR0du2xL0JXfjKUs6QJIoN4CvbM0WsNVI@QOXNC5uKDu6@ICjXMuLkQvhlUTLiP9JiXuyC5F9hrgSlgzkcblT50EhxMAwx7tgAom4MQZb9wOJQVwDgdB6jDV0BlYgbEDzg/RPshgLV9ZLuLsxGE79CE80ChDKa3gELa0isfE8FQYGyc@ybRS5LPAFR286sDvuw4dVk0HgJLajhcv@MHUK6E9dK51MgPhudDpNjGMuEFWsC7mOvwWAp@nxQ2XNIUc0CbLzI5GKz6lTRhyXFp9foZxaPrhq5SIECYbLaBx0zZ7gNIp8O6M2eSXFtRK98DqdICR8uK6N27gcqZD0pzbzu0GZ/Ol2BvdtlrBKfHCJoxuaBDzwEBOJXG4os9Ka6BNbWaBstEXCItmMgwPUCyQkRbFgu86PNa5cyMbS7ugjNXksxh8VIS3oFxgzfJd7paHV7td6U6MzvT5FJ@aFouWJAdiK5fBcX6SONe1SuuUGtqo9RU5JQfn/KGTm03othEcO6jggZdl6ZFDggctwJjBbWtAwXVQaaPlNTU0SXXYY7ZckuhuCpcml3m2AIOv7CWgQxgkRWS5dZ8QMPLjlvwYFxOlRymUhZzXMH3Ayuim8@IjXmYLAhxfUMGmzJtA8LIae1mGocajGRkvKHIGoGRkVU5Agvhi9eMRl7zTSUEognj4XFNs0/MciiZdgShhdE@vMCOu3GHYS5a9aD6YsOvFwVTcULMt7Nf45VZZ@TVaYJV5JtR3aHiMK4ruyqTszhUDc016oJ00W6Ldxe1ERyN7mDhEY8Fy7kKAehTiUJQzZP712C/DF3DIBiCBTGSxoBBt1HtxI4qgHTWeSVFoVGJdilKMY4MItn0QKG2gZ1Z@jFarTyAhdbHQ36mz1KZCJZEekPP7DllyyzlNpqTC6hghJUHw2kT/0PZVIoP3QHDdcTC9ni9uFNY2yX6aOdlBtlffbGSXjKrMzIGlOz1/6F23Ljtu9wqUBdb/0BwZ44/fMra6wnBDSekJ33dfXKvmaWv9Op1NsUmHOy0GB1/Q6Q3nMmO0uxfP2UgzFm4vqizghnv4ZPGnLFemuJQt9QIu5EbUvfpao@pUC5Ve3WlUnExGHWSqg0wxo6DHk6JaAUnLp13qgwZZReaX2MvAdBGPbcW5VbfNjl3H6Lppn9ENmfE1PdozFjSgnt6Pt6crGHW4Xtynjfyk9xINcdqLLo6aSGm5QbzBuG@iaAytPm28Xhh/Hg3XVirT4VjCR4/QRLkidNN4AW6k/rBpWwbIIKInqhhorlguC6N7gyHfgoBCP4t7clygB1IwuBKEGm5/LBJbPMpFUJatGMhtBfsuNfuQmEGsJvDkBR6y70E0HoWTNxGdAWjqelSOFbpfmE7Yz@A@CbWCVuRsIQgLdlRgfOQb2tdwAeof7YKAxxYTUcnGmKnCopd86xYaFZCqtp3mQY8@DHt96t81jq@gCN4gdNHXLS9MqflDvFtMYUUkhhUgjTWAjlvchXcFimW8aoK6wIkFWtzG8iC8YzoGGhA2dLxpEGQjLu4gvJZLaR7xK6oU6AT5xBVHQ6SlYqiiqoFweIZaup8uM5pnqIAXdTmVWOgHCMWyzgnuQXBPH3TnBHcR9tCfF@xBMF5cNSfYgmBuczI73IVwrknNiTDAWTRg14uBezHQLVvhBtNoan3LBbbCMpmAsCELMF4xvD6S6ZkwPWcLvHY4syXYC9onsRWPgCytiMaD7xG3UCieuqFwvojlyWnCbti9mYnJJyDxBeUEYhfzV5cS8FkMAWh/IErZdHiQOa/tsKAJ/tGg2@lgbQOxltmnT3dhJhgxyX/FRsB9vIZwnjNWQk6tCA6/VyeqV57oo0g0O40wzY9Lt0AHjcoRNMpSJEJ424raddsCfRGSqqjlRN44pFTZ08in7jdYOZQeER15s7ifjqUp7sERJ7XILGtGTuPhVNWR7yGlDj1yMxIWuA9Lr0yR0w9j55KxtyF2SM0JPjMSPCNa6ecW9mGlSQF@1KiJNhUuaA1QDbcFgjPQ03m9xmUCB7aYLnN/vAXISgKz5gDj@xUvAMBgC3DAni0Q40GfaDkat/kBOV8orWRpCp9HuY3IFAirh9DpH6BxIeFElz3EixGSIonNIM1U9LDcSK/tySY3UTwu6WcXrs6NxtJP04gjm@Yn4rqn0EuWWYGFG2Mq7PZ@OfTbUeYmqr6EvuMr82VFUOkBJz6EBW/nEPpeJksWodRgCYoP6bb6/r1dEm3ynN0pRUsXF4FPMK3F2/ZcDQyxqiTDEWcOMAgARTmeKit0ru1IdIrdrReDQLnJRloY3kfEuQJU9ooUF@c4nDugzjvuG27NIYrEQ9BSEDVML8DMage6LajBQTrNuMBq5kRGekKb7rhuSwkUJqEwEITAAhoiZfl2oVCt4upllD1kJ5Re1hFW1EG/WwGfBeFF/Qp4oPIpeBORWOpQs6lgs4npN5ZP12VROPZGkFWwuoOTQVz6sPKkP8YOVaBHMxMFEh/3fNHOYCHnqSdOiAd5V3dw4o3OBKOh9ZaM/mFFYJxtGGhH@4epDm5nzDLwPdJi9/BNfOhiVSwNdeKw0oNZJrUSYrO1JWM20UEbv0kt5Ie@R1cim84VKNXNsZRipsMvTCjjpaO5DZyIxTtDhTSheW@a5AE2gZrC3DTHvFbEvaK4S1tWJb7njyaFihKeB0Hz8rZ51QKtn1vE911/RL9jGCwUtGF/4FKIyIj2BrJP1qdov3qBVmnFiEGgs0VwojgKrt9w3zGfi8oVuYJUxLMu1BiIOqYkgSufyzLWHyIq5uvqDcnXTN3oIhLIe5/4cAqqizj5VvKDqse9bEgKXBwEp82tePs0N4dZkHbij@kdio/vRXRwH5pCRL4X4xSJJlwxxHbdPjI5TrVh@i0gACf8o9Ozvf2TE02cdcxXBHAVgc8TowkGbQgUdwKLaVJcDcDtmLxSHmFhETbPrxoBJ/lLNMJsBZmwKVwjOTmtcL8nL0GuSG9TxQjjqzw6kYSWk8Wbj7QsCKvpPuhRSLsomRJLlguSBZFjpHh0LzV0w0BD25dmzwWMd@mC6iKnxaOIHOhEigT5Z8L8/Trm2QiR5@G5qfBcIlzj4RypKJZmdL0oUjkeSU7dRPFumRxFy07lVWVQ6MNXtHtHc70Y3pW74voaDNKsKPJ2WJWcK8OArURALhbybkbt85CFRJqQwcPwOg8X/F0SNR9imYj7LJk/PiVRQSbZuAqTkAku1RzL5vdURyEkYRluW@HJsb6J7XijFBMiQpzkQEzgpb3YbLerEZRMMZA41Gbk7a1nsiampJ4qk2io/GrbyYY1o43EqER5ZohwI@pJIB8KXoiBIJjIaCxoudtB4rFIPI6BxVgLQbZSsBM72cChaJNNvIrT5p/wJ2jsSeSCeKnZgY845iNeeL6SlSQQCd0FeTaZktJk4A1N7ikKdUcvEuU9noQ4W0i8cnEEanTpbuYgT5Ovt7XdodNaCOVEXFAEkmKK7mGIoHQUoRiw77wqxMBb6Tf5JekLvQdaoW2OWA11ap1OSJISi5l4m7KPR4PhGZbMH/b7tiX2zbFrWi7j5SyWVnGxJ4IYUxo06RANcHj8LLrE4iMk0tgRQr5GO44owMf7teleVoYXv4FobVsAcqBJNWfMr4zFbWYlvqRosqHPb1ini@RjSPCa460nvIZXk4KFW17UNm/fzgBUICi46/H7xd12WZJ@NLSMy90vWKlQWC8WlosxkgVT1QVteSV@PXgYUCoUC4XV4ook7br9MTcdUQwVYa3kEGCWvcCO/g3wpnmFF7NJNegxKCIegemb3pXZ0iTpxGzRHHBzSBRBVsab2umUCtpHjz6gW@F5Qnh3sZ/lFxQDh@ET@2d@NoBBhstZCddo@6bXswZ8Jde94lfUB@vSbde23WuaiMYlYU4PTNQzB0CUJZUlUaJ9/wIX0l1oOz5QQxf3x@pN94rO6RBkAD3VwuONaIFVwk2qCCGeGb98MoYJ5GfYutVDdpqBAO5iiSgQIABFaw0N804cJELiM3EILsZtucYQTz7Qg5rJg/Rzqa1Aczc9C6RvRGCqFUoWwx0q@Oz54Sk7PTo4e1s72WfgPj45enO4t7/Hdr5hZ8/32e7R8Td0yCt7fvQCpMspq73aA99XZyeHO6/PjsBDrp1CSpkCpNqrb9j@18cn@6en7OiEHb48fnEI0AD8Se3V2eH@aZYdvtp98Ro66y@yDCCwV0dn7MXhy8MziHZ2lKVcg2RSlI4dHbCX@ye7z@G1tnP44vDsG8rx4PDsFWZ2ALnV2HHt5Oxw9/WL2gk7fn1yfHS6z7Bg0t7h6e6L2uHL/T0N8oc82f6b/Vdn7PR57cWLiYIevX21f4LIJ0q5sw9Y1nZe7FNOVM69w5P93TMsUOTaBeIBgi@y7PR4f/cQHftf70NxaiffZAXQ0/0fvYZIEMj2ai9rX0DhJOUeqkC97L4@2X@JSAMlTl/vnJ4dnr0@22dfHB3tEa1P90/eHO7un1aY9OLolAj2@nQ/y/BmF8oaYAC1IBzcO69PD4luh6/OoM94fXx2ePRKhUp@C4QBLGuQdI8IfPSKlxaIdHTyDUJFOlAFZNnb5/vgf4I0JWrVkAqnQLXds3g0yBCIeBYvJnu1/8WLwy/2X@3uY/ARgnl7eLqvQoUdnmIEgIn5vq1Bpq@p1FhPgBd3ArNKAedmqTrZ4QGr7b05RMxFbOCA00PBLUS23eeC5tCW89LMJbc7F/CmV/nEVMjdh/DsHu3tg8bHz@GTI//X0OlsJBfvEmHQ0YSB8CpWQamvumiZzWHnAi@Nx6F5mIyvYPf8ThZPslTxJp5z6a5r4vhCOSVIpS4u3tQuYJx7enGhZh@SMoHGfSnELve7YqmijLart2iYn5hbihNq@4k4SyfLD7aIz7U8CScfVJbPt0yRDI1DEHAwTSQOfQJgLZSMZDWiOyyWJS0xJ@eK6ESyycmiYHnT9eHH@RS98L4h5gHCmdst5PM4hiU08GQ5FuIPmdCha@LkNbIDsNqUpeab5mVHKcSzwyG/mKBSgzQUdwDDwI6i3pO8aXYmkucm0xOyaMtDykpw3E5wDA6/sRffBMmYqBfNo5IpfGqPHmqADWUESqHKsyJDIWF9ojzhyXH/Np8rVCvhUS103NrL2teHb3EwVyitVCb8n4f@vG2hVR@eHQj9XZ3SNejxvMEjQAOzcPgFJLHGfEk1n4@lAa2M9MkwMp4F1MVI11YL@lTsqrsmdet4AhE/jiGeHjpjzxrFsQcx/MVJ7eXO64MDkJyI7crG6vpaRRInGnmDr7P8@Q3mg2fjEnVBi762QE2joFgr2QW952DqMMLY6YlYexgRDyUPKo088cbicGcy1xH4@WV8GgiL6@MJTg4eYibjIUyezO/kXpACfp3ZMgUDKImiqlianj4iDV8HVYl4wOC7kO0x1doIfxB22PyDJh4WSDCQYDGz1x@MgXNhcEFyTz4IDDppbENmWxhFkwM@7uuBDRInDMpMsnJFG0d6E7wdq0XQa7Gisb1StVNKQGJhEovgEDw60hKyOHb9oAVzTwt8vhb8Bs5vxOGLGIRHadUGp0DGgzBlLjgckc85i4YhIDe2q1BFT56EOW0xnEhVBVJ8/j95NF@8NRAq3KCBTQAOLI9COochNAn9LK2yG86peGoKwqkIjhXvwLmziiOgVIIjZ8R7cEIf47CiA/vI6zrMQwqifBNECcmZINPvRA@C/9@QJjPgb8GAE6BH1CI5bDlD84GUJKicVjB6JaJY14HFWMxMLaJm3OubCMxtvGK6YcGEGd6ILywBCUTtjAOPb/iRrcoMAiCT47xGvP3iAQnUiLs6jJyeUdt9xFf6Pcfo9ZXgwNOgq5iC28iSzpUNTOTwReVL@AUWy@4Fnl/3jPbRkszAARdIseaYPfZlDiNTJJmDhc4v0aRH2MqJNZEMxaCFR@xUEE0raPwjYWEU9TKtIPQWVNH5h6mGyyF4ZmNC4AcrIIEAIduneIEF2SDPbUR0ZrnRkp5m@ZnoxfHEcRCB1C@zMzJ/9vU2jZmxKxK2ymgUjVkinMctcSZm0xxcY3dhc@hkox1BY8pjMhPHTMRcZKhGBMJX1YDq1Mleh9jTNCXya4j9a@fSwfs4TD7FFcTQEidsxre4a@ylTodt2g8rtxxlnkGybifzP3TIbt3g65U4NUcjd8gFR/qP/YgioHFeo3YJ/VBEJd24RE854FHrOmeN4EF55UTJgzMjYcxAJwLPUvpv5w4IkFcmbGCZfO6Ek0hl3pFVHwfqC7p42w1d36BLzDNXoVCAHPigwaxQgxBl1JvQSHO6tRF@iW0LaHxaBs3p@lpr6sOe7rT1nmWPyer0g9t18r4z9Pt4F70sy8nZQDxoBU3QAfeByd5aTsu99tkONAecSDp99fr0ODnxF5v52uUzX4x9CXmwHcpZmgLfxj0pvtseQNWYFTYW9zR50XQPzROKmRaa1hqjB2788YiBIN9eqBl/8eo1@8J0TA/0wWOyuWQvLMN0QHyAMkVWmH6XSxqMfoC5n4rc2QHqLjSzU2GmRZM64dyeJDIQ0LLIWgo0RUDYE8dW49z8GFg9NieoTRc4KlcrmFTqun2x2wInTVHZ5FOc7aGdlfBs7LeHZ89xMM4H5jQ3A91aMNeHc4lcderxyVoojKc7gzEQRZqcvAG075u70RhttgCI0nxy0qCuh9f4tHDaz/ahqHjJlpAC1INAUzWtKzyMl6bhHlJHZGcrps0iulXE/tUsPx44EB2J2pOi2svimexalq1usjMTeZcd27oBIyx2OsTky8ugB@64/gCjvqwxVigVi8VccRmnaF@f1jRqCPgNTmiVpMOXx0cnZ0BIcQRRwBhhn4nEp0NRuTUWkCOHR6NC6d@jQA7ig8QsvSfioQoenJMgV/iKhVyWoe4NHad7oYR@Uh2mKVmcknc9OpgVd9sACyWaI@TqX6Pw5UsjlFMMepaOhhWHu/KuJcSTdktSgveImw18ZeN66HtKTH4gAMwR@UEqj0YGLXGsENRJz@yF2FuDoHfXeQRp8kzZkGB8LhWYI51No5YE1FPjcFom2kj4eDpTz78yPJAt@hWwHJqwBFuOgGdINqlhafSmZVvQBgAvo@tih8PFVVARNAURP3FWohoPzzLEDolwmXEaFLSultsLo3KsJCncbCf8@/7YcFmqA8NsHGn5fdNs0UlUwz4/agnDNWjlNvQcfBteOTqDSUoVyG7SA2GDR96B7BvauDcf91I2eZ1LQWmAq4Ltm2ddHNZzQFCi0wE1UjwRV5kxws4yXOdVqdp1YAhMqyIh5mykBBD9LC5KAVZQ38QQ5CJ2yeJ2H5vqe3KfJSakwx79fjIAYfFVXTMZEIDHsgvnVATOpNUQgYktnAEyfB8SdyfmwJIvWF60O8VNaQovIxRurIbEPLDwiHI@N@Cyjou/GFkLKMbXCE1aI5zaGIo3ahYB3mTM4nRMiBUe0BaLWZoBMzcT5vJsmDkBUyxWHjpXtCEOUxFb8FLw0zZckI9IiKj4X7iB6KVte7bLF5jC0ndst4nnYoKkgNzwMc5GFRv3phFYgtDxUL5JM3me51ZQJIG62NsU6C5sC9qHuc22ghmL7XOHV5QIqPK2RHvCGPVd1JzIiT@iRZFTThwOilrHxOmgiB73BdmNYGUBUvjIZRa1TLTEiccXOSeT9BJJihNJBHLJJM1EkpIU7QSfqF1MgaIfn8mSBXoJWSVRDbBqWEEFqaeP@OimQBv8aJoGj@RO7DgsNQSDYMS6wcI9gxi9IUVHYCSW7XkewSuZ4JHFt7wo05GiheR5UqPAdI/EAMVKhI/pmBVHEQVSBRnoJTxeQw2QEeXaoiROTFKFBeYBUqLYHu7VUuK5qGWW6ut81RBj@dixxbOuEw1wlV6GvyWmiAxycWR5JDy2QIhCIDwdbVGHoSyvlkAOFqSoZ6a3mICDGpS4/CaTMd4NKEqiXQWSO4TJnVOyG0ChPwdHOUl8f7UPeh33xR4lJhpOUeHDY@KFkmeOYHhGa8wEgvqfcMZaePIzI0LpIZCvRzk3gl4jWYq5sSe7kllxYr1KSIW7IgfEDuk0N/L83oZIh3MIKO949BjpXuAksSBd0AWnfU4y0lKsAW0mdw2LS6gk2WJCl6fNzhDAySoPkMtOlEqKHRUjSjjZjUiJnjPBJErsDa/BYY/5QcEckColUiH951U4mjvGG/bceEUeT1T7PI4IYQX1fhdbhJGDer@LLXjkWLXfzRbBWdEhaSn9JF8kaoKTAI0SxYiB5pTiMigIGMVjjSZiEULjRvysGNNWZmAbk6pirlOaUpVCEomj4ZJ50GPEKyYlNnIn2BGIVw9roxGVFvo449JshSdeiNKHQ6RtOdkl8NqcPOgJCx3kQHXUUPFKkjABSGw@CSbGzD1uu0knBqX5gIXGoHgqaqeb3N2bABv0KgV1WqEMTkeKkN@aiXxu@pSqaIhVnr5/J7QuE1ijwZPrtTC2LM1Y8ZXuwSoTwypZulgNJUk8B1LuQZByD4CUj0ESDXsZ@ktypjw8B9i8D8T5@TQMeryDgZSAAZK2ZeEkNo6Dr/XxfTAXQNlKkU2dzq3KwgSRnnwfjKeTMOjc9W64Gic8uzrOun00PXfy1LO5lE3yygyMQqxS02hlES2S2jTeFfECVYnGttpls2uFI4HU/TXNz4kQidGUuBsuAqWSpxaFwKL2X5xDv2ysWpPtgSOemIYBbVn6zOagISH4DBPfKhYmiAmy5DhUBCQJcXfopPCj0erk6RJ4oPzcZOq9JXnGJ3xik05FKBqXWAmOC4ZwkXAKeqtAvs0ant2bf2pm/n23DzpOeyYCFL@H8/h8UmpCpEeq6cTQ@kF92cz@bLpccb1t4uy3hzfyJ1NFL0HRcWM6NGrHvBa9/12QRVmCGvgtNPl6wCNzkHw8E0lcaNfF5BZzhr2m6UkPaeo8hYYPPkaaz7mSlEqxmgFDZnHyEN0ARccjmyJLVIOREXw27ON6jc@NO7Fx4xyZyRl4Mi5eFE@xNRmzoDnanqk74igi0WF2PFy/CONm8Xh03NxFOViOAYT2zdj053t@50fLFCFokXwHWSuz6x65mi6y51hko5wEWlzXVMbJMS33naPghFoNxSpPKioB7@Bi6BLXzIW@BIq5OnsK7CHa010KETDxvCzFgHcC9N08Wp5PzGE/JGVYNQ8g5Sx1K5zlfoC6NX6ouvXfgJKTFSrF3EJ7EB1s@V6hNjnIpwtvg4OvezOObnlzdnCQOPCkOQ5GBT3TWy0UCngIztTtdrhAgavElptPxs7jnHi@f/2l96aZx6TJ@@xmXmeHOEBUjI1LE8gnuDQxhP4mdpwWzuc4uCvng89j8hN4WozMOK3QuP3NGTEfgUTimWX2HguI5XvPgsulQXHkQwYBJbA3g9Sohl7JgZkckAc92niiTmiSRsBo3Cx2LeDCR3X7RnokrnikeT68jke9ibYhys9N23az7K3r2a0Fme8OTSY4OIgnKPAoaErIG49P10NkmXll2bErMjAK4ubapma7HX7HEt6fy2c/aS@TZ/ZxJU3BfuzE7OyP@opcfycDY0KRM1jMDJMbuL2nI0MXJdMS@v1g@YFkgPaDYvf0vmIQnSYjQx8o9lJFLsBoGS/R5NbBOJ@yC0VGYw4lEUXl58Jwmt0fG4k6G13tg2s5ChQdgyXcLkdbv6l6qSRzoofElc9HxTbSsMBhCJzwCMSHpbit4KFTv/0HZ7dx5gA3N9Icb7glNnbeWLwcwWQ8tix2NWi3oXnxmfjt4KixAByJylyRrBSQNKJiPfPbIegzSrrtp/kBdmhqczp2jAQi9VIjy9LDQXsjDRB@pzJKQQsUzQ/oiWYTX@WgWR8M6Z6USJ7RNBwaUEzLHUxwgQkk6bFR/fZaqdVqbLGfybBabQccuRyr7dTYHnrs7LA9eN/B9yfV0upqhVvO7ak34LkTeN6yHYBBXRDeybYHrxBGVy3hUAqreDFfXcxWFi@qW9sVP1@v7TTy@Q64/u73f/J3//RP8jXx8j2@7NBL/V0YSdO0/KJxs/jktoLv9b1GerFZX@w30p0KchmK@9eer9t6bJuYZvyD3Isb7Jw3VAYarVqtpln60yfuOh9ETi9y4iUGUXLd7nd1Ss4IwnY1XUs/eQKurWr6x2kVT@4Q/nro/xH8mYqynNaLibS0fFw73T08jN8TFN4/2kZNExfcdWGcZjm@BYV6nwpWz3N1pmmskWPvQ/TQoPuCR0yiyNJoMcqR@U4gGZQOMQsAUHOQGzk0SKvm6sW11UYulUrJ3EzNIsy4fSpZIHHDKG6u1vM7ZH8UWDBRGFmLYaLHrTK3rSMYGZCIGL/Cd60qvD0@yBQOOprwTnF2w@i@W5lf4zqOXa8Xu1oXzxCZvHc9PLc2unmdLl4PABoTZxtMAuSmdzBepjpBS0CGlSveoQOfrqb34v4bthKs1Yg97K497th4HSVtQ/Cvob0D3VVxRbLtBOcMYg48ZdNs41IibyNEsdg2OFK1TNxd6hg4Xw8drWPjsbRchQouIgadDDgMdQZxskUbd1ErtsON7902OFW8ND64cJnqLUPHJVGd4LqITYeu8PRBy1rqgzbY5zGRqvAeGa5iGchsWpg8PJo2YeyrIiUtkeFuUmDWfh1t5IqN4Hh8VbCe3O31eiBPOJOFxjCgr/VwcIfTDUAcTKHRWa7Q6Mbsve28n3UhM9n/UdY8uxK38QVZEGZniSVNyo5vp5VVXio8@dXRB4LMfdf3LWECIqqL7Fv4/lsPoJ6nJZ6Z4Jr4ldVLfSpoKsrY5q2Ts5Q5An7HGSZ@mgfkDoUU3JCIiGaRaNPHLc5SCUtXurcchVnTHFgG34TEc18IpFyfDtpAX34iydyMQC3nhpZBRVMO50zs7xQ2llTlERyiE@73Zf7Q6IZKrU40C4x3OL7BeSj9esgkYe2cR0SKIIacQACSRBE40rSPoOCjBIPaZscaJNJk@XZmsXOTl@I2ID029vdkSxij7gRl0eomuDM6FA3vBb0D8@Y@iKMgDCTlBrdbns17QWGwv@BWTmFKXiQ6kmJjmj9CuRSgE8caWjKQD5txNllD1G1hL2L5nI95nUSsyqJauDMHAi5Q5HJjifbIEwAhNSZpkqvjzbkT1ACxOtEMImlcSICPMTAyd7yPJFk1QV5eXbyznRLiAb8EmN7OuAn@HzPfRFU2PTzEFRofxEI@AFUgMtNuQgzHiPSGEOTMFnhtBiowimGLdgZ5Qxt0am7@LXqW@GXrUaYhHhNZBUUXNZwjHaQfHAVWT8frciJpUN4odSOZOpfmpyLcBGcjxDmGa9RCVNAQjk/bioMURJpHvKuHvjbIjR@FoBSC19vgzAZx5EFoCR7UmagI6nz1NhINbctRxkdVdjuLYYIxcyD7A0oIvQNNUeLACRad9SPixe3rZ5DulqZMasOBezj4h9ehaa6MsLHaMc1x6AxAa9BB7RQKhK7mhQucdboy@h9IDce6tqCy@c4Q3TfBLUlcLxEjOvml39lxR0oh@/@1dwWrbQNB9Fx/haxc6iKDU0ogpA302EsDSW8JWI4sUoNdG8sulOB/z8yb2dlZScQhFHLJTdZ6VztvVzPvrbSju/wuL07Pzkc5dKmxtJOqIeZwUtX8BvOWWXmtWo/is76R9rcWx769X8znxEf0YwVUVa9mRVNt9pZXpB/NCTZjBOAcrr3OnYdvxjSIOKFY43iznT2sZjj8uf61nf37QaEJP6/@yHjecHvXFKL4o6UouZY79/ucCEh@YF0a58SLTMQS9Yz4ULUDYdjVkprASEQPAHUHALmm2d@kxjoYvP2yVmDcGtGUBrUU3tLIu9il5OArIRB4OwDpoqmco7mp@qNB/jg5RJHIhTa95IKwc8adlRoiBJbZJddJUujFDGaYeB9xNalVZEuaoBMomKOmrGWnYWm9b0qVPbvq93S1X@4WalnHrGAXVyoygWLPX/RQMzlrH2efW3zjDUdfUYh0xoHB8xJdGztnB7d7u6C7NCodOKqIgkq00EqFZanQS/QD9mOZL1IJFTKSMf3zF8yPyeHimbER7n8ZhAgnNOekaW44YC9j7sSIZPiz6JuZ1cNEmnA/CBTuxqcN@2RxzQc/xjzCnHIdzsQG910CPy@B5QxDNo0oBdWqry2LDxMnzavX2K9bZJMxVue95qWZgsrNehXeblSR4aSt@6wy3UG8Y/ut5ewRPZdwQgdV2A/pGc0wudESyhg2ojk4jcQgMvtRgK2ejHgmAZez0YxjgnPukkRyrO9xGyJV6J/S5zb1DozJLO1xb9REJ3gWRiM6RSO91AdjQPgrzal5cKoa3WJg04evvIoWI1joa8o0PZHPYgCNTLZHmts0OApU3QXq9HVASb/6cJKS/wZTCkCK0mEw6Ju@5jp0g6a/121vfscvAbihEeFWGz1EF88RXcfazdEABmZ/LmT4CQ)

Agena has `#`-initiated line comment and two types of block comments: `#/ /#` and `/* */`. Different block comments cannot be mixed in Agena –
both `#/ /**/ /#` and `/* #//# */` produce an error. This is a problem because `/**/` comments are already heavily abused in the polyglot. 
I ditched this issue altogether by using an older version of Agena that does not support C-style block comments (they were added in version 2.9.3).

Agena 2.9.2 is no longer available on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/agena/files/Binaries/), so I reuploaded it to [github](https://github.com/stasoid/Agena-2.9.2).

Block comments do not nest in Agena. There is `#/` on second line and there was no `/#` in the polyglot before this answer, so it is sufficient to
add `/#print(171)#s` to line 218. `s` fixes both alphuck and paintfuck.

Grass seems to work fine without final `v`, removed. Removing `++++` from line 218 also does not break anything. `>` before `/#` is for brainfuck.

**Update:** Escaped `{` on line 17 to fix Thutu. "Unescaped left brace in regex" was a deprecation warning in Perl 5, now it is an error.

Answer (score 6):

## 176. [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 9001  bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x             -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                       _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#--++  
#  
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f x0t0g4O6O@OOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss  
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796los*81''TcTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1
>y#a=128
>x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001651

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcxtJkiD4Wbn3D@5LMEEJmQSQePANEJAgiiyxShLZJCVVNQhRiUQCSDGRicoESEAUy2b2znrnsXa329M71ttzO9U9t2c3Zrcfxnb3zHZtxuzMbr@uzY@o@Th2dv0P@tw9Il94kFT3jO2BBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeES3d7/3mNyn8sCPXnnRtd8iGpj9kbc@6ND2NPZ2wJ7rlr5dWJQlj1b3uqG86Q78spViRMcsxrDa8s6F7YTrWR9MD/xJjA8/tenqfDXv6kJm@oQ9Mn7mj4WA0ZG5nfrJVxvb67gcrhyn7ltOFaEPTG3jmkMLXGHvt2Hq/1danQtanMhx4EO6zZ6b9qf9pyAy339edtg8xNxh76Xq@ifEN0/ddTL7J2HjPNKaAbkFU3bPcF/VXX0wFbTP2BaCoD2xzzPSWP/R0Y2i5DtKkwE5evT45mkpRLLI3p/v7074l9lXOddj@yLiYDlplrz1ft/Vp@GusPhq6B8Np/3VW75qOzkratlaaDtxgTz09mYSq88hz2yMDST3smYABVk/Hsk1fMiB6jQ0EU2joYCnmmXqbR5M6rscwCetf2MxixmDAWrbe0wxmWxB3v7DFTKxN9hHC7Z7PxoM@860@QPHdvhkvrs8c02wzf2AaVscyCANmjoem4wOmvsYsIM@VZdusbdqQIELLyAIwNvJjXhwJTWq7EoOPMZgqRPi2bEIcxwwIYQ6gspEQLvIGUCWgx5WnDwaAJNDxBBAfWn1gZWuY9pmp@xY2Fkjim06baDgIm5HLdCdeSnZpQWUCviOPYPumhxWhEVzWMz0TQOohIytXnjUEEiCJ6@zI1D126pmmmmxSiSwhMxdzGGJBNKrCnZ303uF@GqqSp9D0wVBKeaunP/pS0plWZcvnFfhWZbki7b16xq6Xz9DNWxBU98BTdJVVv2N@/uzMhO@42Mp3vRsJoEpAFZvl3cEwr@cGgGBuCAjmdXSiK3dZ0gZ2LGO2M1UXMQbjsdpQG@zAYW@yVDJj5HkoJSKi6hdQaNt1ukBPKKw3cpAeDtsoQBUYLjTyLDMvgWrQqqiO3Cui8GnPgkrzsUpijYDLOiIoSDvgPUHRIF/ftUcUD1L6Q2RAoAokRYgHHfaGdXTLxiQQjqA41p7pj@whphk5bax5kGVmW2MBGobbxkh99xKy0wEoeUB76sdaISEFkaEiXCoqBv3wL/6s3e0CnLphuF5bsOsb1nYNkso6IQuijiHDuo5uE1oQL4u58@SQwaVuW219iNk7E5EFIUG5Xrkju81cyNC7sqBp9fRLaI6djmkMTc7kXJBnWV@/4LLD4pwLBe/rLahYyoDypmLn2JNdqCXDlFLEM7n@aNjZYrnBHkv7@XfK47LyeOnMBORUTV1Zzue7FWA4bYW84C19G@e8qSdknT/UfddqS4PJsOc6JZYzmGxU3YHpKOkEjHQ27bXSqoYyTVErVtXQOpbTVtI7wIs1yDitVoyq0bDKzcpU8niWAOYKwWBzNRVDlSUQOdQoLvN93XK0wYS9yQlXLMz1z5HkGKzFvJEw036X3CNFHRnypYsMAnJI823THCgFraiimMB4c8uNAfNKOgVDFLhsNTPpVDoTLzpBgJImCoqN9dRyUWzZgx72YUAUxx@A@PaQdw0duMdHKT4EbSLLWsTXJPpBspBMvDLTnslaIEgDPqImyZscps@hoBQQoiaUbMlmO9aQQQhAWx76M9LYdq8gQ8IJ@y4QHQ5mqnehaiAxL0idF4TnRD7JIl04IFAQWstkW7mWBY0AmxvIdMHzsbJB9NUSjwPQeCOJyZ6@PgEoBu8LowbDrA60pT6IB2/CDBNlDggfk3comMmI2p8P@hNqUoVcaX092cZmmtjQy9dzPwYh/TF/a0vCwtcTKgL0PB3zitm60x3pXVThHEiiG4Y5GApBBSXxhyCKpvsb8syJzlPze9Lyk@m8qRMR3WosDxTyvPZEV6ijdBFKXM4GYcp0oYaytuWBWLIn07lDhMupzOX3GCWBwHt5AQqBBgBMZo5NYzQEqQYMfNWzjB7wLGLncLnIO6Hp7MErnjtI9lwnzBqRKdYelSQtH3ohGgtB5LBGZ@FA54qgagkPqvy4x@2Qdb8/B7AboggdQcxXy@sa8N4dMPuu484BCoQMwWKUZAivB9DETlALhI4rULuosYaqYVhFUGcgNaDlA//1hsOBX4Z@whr2Ri0NOCV/6k0OhocOMkt@6E2socvdLdttgVj2oX3mgxzyxqhljacKRH5hHX7wpUtQwDo@q0LP/e0IuE5Jd3wQmOS/i5FjQTIJbgLBf2WISJE0IJTS8UkU74NQOZk4hiJr1JQ0aHRylsnYcGUVHJgqpMuu20cpxN6SYoCaHqj0ltMBaSVkPol8fW5XF8p@0uvSae2DaznKdXppaSldTtdAsi8tPQbXDroeoysDrsfkypEL42noohRZcmFog1KgXzN90wggj9UmVtsYe6WP1kDRG@XyajOrN4riWcKnCqIOJBvEzuED4KTVahWdqirXrqCgWquTLP0uSucTw7MGgghf6pc6fxdUWCUyWP2B66ECW8FO9naa9Kse9IKgtBo9xUufNQpnzbPrs3bm7CadxdRqRa@2oFCQn9LXup47gu5SbayVc8WmqjZWoZNsVdOF9IqibOVsyEhX1Ydbakbn1FbSJkht5ewsDUQV9GkYPY/gjbMlVQ1JBXhgxww6oZLWrrcg/5baVDNpSKumszDEqKbTQBkDieBToZEziUD7wIC7Jy8So8j@BYhHZvg26hI5j6sT8Jpf4Z5teoQqU5kdkMrpQH8JKEB32Q6HNo7r5JwRKcCknbrxjGgQhjHIDzsPFIxWIg4C7lhj0PCh4U4CTQY7YFRmdmGY59qm9pZ0C5kB5zNsr9pcdeaI9wua4UeVCIoLOAe2bkDLTII7k9kZAARGzefnh6iVGcDTug4NS@4qI/QMhu4g/doWqd0jy@8heUE1wrGA1wGqos4NnbtJVDtgBnTaXaC0ObaGXAkHRjjBJM91X1FR7atztQm1NezyEalgyE79sWvAgMWErh9D@eiP7TmXluc6SGRtD0ADx1awDqaAzyMvsFG9flB6tpi@84ADxWa8izHaxqFOE9fwDZZ3XNvtumwFIiBrahpn7APHABRAaRvC@JD51kciUL3rwsglyYMm9tc@KnnFjdVQfdYxZp7iax9AWLD5hY4iLCjzycGP90DEF9cLBcA/eCvQJyxkDMp0GdHTYFEE0Wyh6Z/2RqZkGj2XyWfQQZZqLN82L/PY3GToiXqg6eVAmzI90iXCZGJ2Sxq6I1BK2qZt9a3hAc3N2A72vFGvEoTuAntFAI4scygJdTnqjHGaJhKUTpfH3xujPPUlk57s1eGzvfOj@unzqpwf@V7etlpQf23zvA96k236Mpv@pNixCcBE@o8X9rHrDqtUQzhBdOcnhWmC5C@enb84eHpcP/6GI0FgfKs/snVEpbw8FQGTn1BwwFOxuaeO5/ZDhdIXFbG8iqQ3E9OROLoSoWsYOhKTkTH/DfTv4wSjZkhdw2A5l7@GniLiJkbESUfNGAykbiaDMWkSMvQUMbcIJE5Eal4r8NxGz3AKMqazx8HNC1@cSEC@LhZuELjvjPxBrGTXxSL5Xw47Hex0Qu8SeV/kAAxom6H3KnnzKcxEVgFZZoLmRg7hrRE8PvU5F95M0NzIIbx1Dg@nTOeDmwqZFzUEtkHAcIp1LqypgDkROVuegkB/4YLwfmH5NE0e51Mp1BLOJDlQdRIajRyFlKIpB5a7nD9XIscBUQsCJr9wUcOOXOcFrbiOUEIQ/Qt7NmUH@jn6SUSdQWo2hLfcfqtDP3MilMUwHIQUTgYjVb7EqUScKXBB6zCvKBoNKAgYUMty9PwxPXBoMQ@f5CApgUzL7IygQ86DxofuO6LltrcoZqfVshZFBbog6sFzTjRv1JpHNhjg9GbG0SxB@OHIG9pmWzz/6@@1oQJmq6enT0gJCR3nQDfijc7C2hJJ8YV@5tcsxfkwsi2dyECuu0AaOk5d6nbomA8a@xOWy/V0r499vahcYE78ARF0C59xzD3THrXN4Dk/EyJxcrTOUztWn0oET1RWafCxIPnUXANPT@qe7eptgsKVMsuMapvXiznm6klMkQEpfw88gykBFs3Bw9h3OOK/OO1@V71aA/zOp0o5yWSFdb1VNPOur7cs8xY@8PSLUdvNDS66VGhEbWMRt/NGhCPYXMfWL7jzHJ3zCcCL6FndLozcxXNRtKseKF3@ANS2/BU9bmGVoJ9jpLnot8H0bP67KEqwqBk6FtPJsunncxiSWMSAVoOkxQWxXIxM1hRhbb01wbFn7/M5CzMkBQIET9XIZAqr2IWFE6nR0ttgsDg99nuUfnt7fmq@SkcADLfTMc27WjP0SFZft3Oldsy5UDgHMyORa05UGg3kDFv3gUmGgszmJVQL/dzGuNjJGMgukesWto3QCebJF025RmkGluHalj/gLUm8LJKS05NVERhci6WfKCm@zdK3DUMe7MBzoWt@Q3eNIU57LuCjewguPuOIc7oxxtDcRbQz3Cv8LlQdeu6lyX/nd2Yf52J1DxGUs4kzLGNO8rZxF7viwhn9zKfixVyshoY917/MXrqu1zMdn5W0QjBFg6sWum3zKdDTg8PFPO1btuvDAAh/b6MFDHR8n//O5@Y42SzdydFEVNw9P5lAasA0MW5fUJm63XXtja1uXoefhTU@8joo2cXzvhItlEjF4p0SKVR8XKcongtF@QX838UMNNnl4ax2zHlLPzpPfInZ0MUFhOEBLlXNL9x@YYtSank@Gl1UAZ7Ru9InwfO36C0WUTfoLQYTUptBr8ME21vgGHpclf5tclu7Pbf2/WTSDNjNuwoRq9wL2wQJTb8zVcpKheJnpigWCveXUB17ZI7MuRLjsPXBRKOiW2TF/ZEqiGIsi3mbPBAPZ23CWB/FoPBeWGP/jW@3ChjdtqCR36m9zJV3A9C1BziOPgLHETpmE3ad0SBRuTHaHY@c49sp1xsELdttJ5DEkM@VSFt360gJddw36btIdd/ruzD0dfugMzj3qH8BlKa6@G8CMPlEkD9YOIfo3Qq3zMLlL9BXQf@AWrUu/BxORN5P8JQWjdkp8vY2jMocczjB30XUnidIW65rf07tgDxtW6iWgbKJ9m131dKMriNWQlk0O@HjTEers2hegvc1YgAJ1MPB8sKKPoIiDalzuE8tz8xl3tJrxWY27xpHQo9Nkz@@ZwTuRfgeY@Mualva5q0Ic3XUbZm2zh/jjbXb4G1rq/dRiQaBnksz4Th7zufLo9Wb1JQIGkyAWFY75xs9s2/S6y1Kvt7@MPKDx8JIYxe/c4K1PM3@Lkg3sKDNO/ibmJuPaUVD1zH9/FD3uiYOT2xcMhG@i@RsMKk8l7gHfb1r7t/JXNHsA5rJ0JJkzDl/HqLMV64NSHaHJOEjP9e5MCd@8JyvH08MqM9R/1Zo89q5gZOcdzZsLT93Lv0Otc/puT2nZ/Y8ahzh26LmARw55BbFtxUC8O/p/gXaBZFMioZ1PT9OXdu17ftQF2Uil5CuO3/@dQ8NcduQ9LPgTvQWBIjHnVN10HUTkagPX9R2euYIeijfHboDM0dvi6LaOKnDf@dPKR8cpn321jK9Nl8TxRk@fWi1bJNdWYDCBz@@tjh/wqhluzqant2ixANlgud9pqAM17urV@jq7nAwoMf5wB759EMzubnO/CnKMtsnRO/DC9aQr0ZzjjW7bsvoWXdVXsvUh451kRetX7zO5/KkLKaCWyz3DL012wJSeRMNeaAaDz/Bx8H8dm@9EPsBbtVHdkeeN7lbNiRXWsNZVb4WgI5F8y9iUWxOMPX8aHIRmBbcsiAh1tAWMhTp0qg358wCKCfFhbNBCfMQQQJ7dXV4B5UM17i4U51YOD8pll@RVIYVW0IG/@lJjNvReC7EGwwOleejrq/eFX@CqtYzq8@3C@h2ZBh1R8p6l3MOLiT5tnsVm2gGkaA74jGX80ov7m5PtBqyfuvCSJkVX5zXDw/uBmbY1sDnvyzXKc1VIWbXVOfl@A1W4e2UOYGW0Ln/4KHvemhLC9pGzvBM38BJcBTUXIBy8eS4XRDYOZtFkYO4c8syu547T41Jdoa5r1@ZXR1Nc15YaKVj@7P9I0CeXtq9D@AfjXTf@tHIHZpzYU4v8d4H5Eu9axnPE1MUUSf@Y3PQm3j3r4KrnuWTMWPgmCuA@TrzMe2aCO1r/azY7gF@lieM@/1wB02KLHDI2jawvmQptAEeYYMfup7GKJ6i6JmMqko8EU6ddh2IFsSiPQxo38y3R/jMtvwhxbU6rNFgy9fjcqFcvGFVJpdl1mxyqGRpuzce0OaDY560saw3q8vpXC69nD5zyqyQpqim7Zvzo@qJeB2LHhzPqOjM0bl9FbqDkla43bbfoz0R0Dm2oZN9DUMzErSux62PuWn7Ka7B/pe/bIutIqCI@6xvQYsEQuD2Jrdv9tyrxzxfkXt9MNBxqwnCgJqzueFzbrfO/CvsjfkOEfeKvd4/3RJ252ITFrwcYbcRw4JXKo4K0ehsyCuNY9N2Tc5KIuMwVVAow7VHfQfUn/aw52sgAciebORFpjHgwmjO0EMdsJ1lB6xt4koXmQnSsMd23Qsy2EVM/stfcmt7MhYURlxB9rTLJpYj2gQWycTdMNwRYB0A@Wh6roiiIJGhfY1wUgEagsn9VTSho20AwIm5wAges@GG8Lv1E5bbY2ncJYamtRWroyzXj7940yg0q9@xft78r7@XV68F3eSHue0NX86yIErlBvkqHrwOwVFomsnLY1kUC/cj0fabkKnEnkcF3VRdgVF7n7YyEd@ZV2TUTqZYDooP3CMEnZkPivdQJdC80VSXlREfvuZOhmwdt9LBiFAHF9/8RCaCaKCNSZbH7BPrIa/kDDRbgzdOEBv3BPSrTwMLhtW4nUn@mdka0eLqZUkrrVapOMvn1Z0auTyz7eLenMa7s3GpkDsbb@41835AnLOz8cNC6Wugngua9fKjPDagvVfPrpe1WuHTJ1@fMFm@SVe44Qy08uXro4OjvZPT@unrE6DmDS9sat/1@nokKZAXyAqv59q06QnI4lmmf7f0CCVI@AbRFYUt62wHt2qqqhQ3MqOogtRyTl7mzjAKDDHjqe9IPi@9b8bCZyMIydSxmJCi7IgYSfBM2o9L0GzAW1gv2NxhIBBSBM2S5ohCopHMqkClHFDpnjRis6XkNfiYPKAa7ybU7TDmgQBaRTFmIyCRwrywvDycF25u4W/@AUo8gH7tdy0xwbi1xBjjthJDxCgZpdivH7x4fbyXTATsFO1whWG8h/umO9S2@F45zl2u2JYVSCYaAftiG0YoW312afk0QkZ@62DPYINwweZINhY@ShdutM3qtg@SvN0G0dSaDFGygUjXyF6OG83lHCangFha2NFmmSxhXL86u00HJNeVAVLsPU@8TPEIsi/N2U94ZuZ/@Bd/xvcQng3B/YfCPS48hbc/Fm8dcP/zIKRYhLd/Gb6V4O2n/O1dHkk5u3GKlyYkIhLwzcER82kQjyTq6@NY6bFvw77TcmAYafWB1pdEOozOixVRJoKjNN4A5aG6gOwopFEuU36m11Rw20s5n0dVBGdeNbLsMsd8CE@7YL4d4e5P6EryG@sba0UYw5q5ywAgWbJ30ZSIA1TVMnCldGkNqu9bBtvZ2WGyb@i2Wd2ocJLnl/V3q/L7ENFliCtxraXBIA0kiVJAWE0kU5b1TFHFpNg408U0a1ZAIeE1CH2aQg6IoqK3ExhDQ6fpClIBezjmeEiCfxJoY6AKOWRea/I9wAGgHADisHGP4jSXR8ZBaEsZ43stXg3yW4x2gtHK8jwma7xjZ8Mzpyn2qjJgmF/OYTkH3H80ZwNryD312Z2TyvS@RywNe3LiuGhEtg/YMqWUL63mixtqrE3JAhTgiy3oE4CENgNt0DCtD@7Ar@/uHXx5eHQyswOQYqano6VZuraTOctp2UYzdKSnuD4g6tP9/MnLp/sBKeNYRWswGCNaiJlGc15u05guyP0tt8qazZsCZjIqFu4LmCYScvu0VjkLPQrNxyLucquRmVwV9fqm0dypnTmpmew/zdsVndJWkLnAdebTnug0myNzDgJbs1M8ScPXAqPkkhzt@Q8Nkfl75L14D194Lke0kS@wapNoj0K4RUHSFti7Qdm1PM@KdrFxxAJ8QdYEqBYR1ShDQ5pZR4tjw0RZZo8QERbZIZEO@UCWNifrDoxhPMvgsX0S0Hy4SztqYcBzMIzGSDDuwskjGgpOaNgDoiKcvmpbNMbXvcA4Pgw5MftW7jTABwVHtDFP7EjrQdlsq1XRq40xC026b9ufpvkD2xoquFlurOFwEkqjqFiA4g7uNhurO9tNsbGPBfvvMrSF72gE9DpyBywawj8zA9cxjOLYsxEABzYw2ZejPsTr0OPYxF7CZK/cHCQGOqYDJBq4aU2UQeu31yF3rWeO21YXehpFzYJIelgsRpv/dNy95qRBDnNSfYHGRXHCfNaGxRjF9IauWU7bHCu4z6bcROqAf/rq7WValWd4gHZNik2E7entk4Gw0Iei1UZbD6cEwvZ2KAiSbWd7W@v5EprcwwgEcjwZei/ACX2o0unrA6aMaP@pzzRGr8qZ4mT9oaeyXA37syvmsEyGxi7woACNUcoOuSwbZ/AVPK5ByVehntHXd9r4@GgNWKOoaU1wUyYqW8bZh11QN3DcrkqgmkKSMoGFDhj@yojRFYzSECP@XKZsJdpBBrHmBlND7vaoAQItqNSs9ijasBRrgZyq29tlURtJcbjNgC125kgMADtHzAW6KdBXGE0D1VCIQaxdGJRaIFCefGU6DrRXBXimD62T6SNgMk/NBkcYZaNjKCiHFEfxubDCBkSTx1Pspa9tF/SZ5XyFRsCVG@j3359hx98RXf8k/9/ntXzlWlm2q5M8KGNqTVnuVYuZ1ZVMZtlZUZYdVEcePcKB880yaDvnmqzJY4iUW7bVCvAzaEfVZaeyrO8oy@1qaYVSwGsmo15Dgu/8vHa9rN/klx@BNpEFH4@3TmXZp52jBU0r3gB@2EKW81ngmWvcQUkHE2H2y1Ymgzhoy@eIwHf5s5MM9StnJ3kao1eEkpvv9gMxktRVwpqYOVCJE1B4l0OJvo4SXay0nweR44dTzAm7Vbv@Cu2SGK2hmL4f569kyP0FixBoKJyEkFH41l0g4FgBIuJrVldVECa/@U2quAGjvscbq4qbebxeqGTS68VKOsVST0BNza/Innx99ix3ycxcutHR17Vvm0cXR0dfq2cK22bp1O6hXFyT37Ht0kpeSuVXCp828/n379@DQswaNa2mNdVGLt1sKMGgbpPVNjdXshtbK9kn6fPIV1VKJfUEqoqdsXV2tqnrK5m10hOnAmHb@FllRXDi7xZ8i2x9ne3h52//49/@/G9/Rn8/p@9fW5Y18Ntt@Lo9dsE@wueiw/Cf3B/bMbeO7lbnowJjDVBBq9Q8ikfp9Ppq@uRdmrHH8FmCP/qHT/iKv0vkI7wpyuxnSUrVjNTHVLFYTE3o7xzdxXFiE2COXseLPvlisXTGpNQKW91YegK0NUGY4qdcfhKDkpc3t2TXJa8e5LLO3BRrH8ZijHP4kVLBeSu5ht5psmEd/9hpC/@Oh/j35iL35uLNxbGBf08v8O9lC/8GPv79qEd/Hv49d/Cv9S3@vfiIf6cGIr1VzTLA@btqlePKBM6zn3kBmnYeuBDK@5331d/twz7nM5BSMOZL1WrNTO7mpqG9y1Qq4h@kZSV8ww93Ab7Nm1xu510tk2kQ3o2aKMBOrlnjpaFf7fzdDoDN7DR2drTzWm1cyzXf1RpYymv8MfwbfJRkOb9ytoLO6njnmIN8FsDEJsHwT3xe8HwaRy9gmHOaLe3kUqX9@m62dPL6aaoIb@vRKwau4uvxXv3Z4WuIffRir36y98XBm73XR@DvN89rT55kNGCVJ4ByrdmQUuOHmVqmOhwOz398vqJhD7nNO8rtGBZTn/M5Lv4qpZ7Vxq/zuR1A@8X5NhbymPLLAUWanxgHLKVyOeQbkJbwbaQaSuZx5nHBLlwWihfFi5fuYfR/eDiGAGtc@OB6hV6hV2xDI2MF83VhUpiMC333sNgGpwl/hT44rUJnXOgWnIJTLE7GCVCL//uH7vDloQvQXEg5HBeGCLgAGhq4umuHG4dPDg9fAtgOoPAB/qxCoTAGXMeFS/gv2EX6vDsvABFU3GANb4XC2ZnUYPJ7EwSnVkxrhbS2kU5bzfWNwbdn1zeljW8bpOqtbzcbtJu@KbNs@vyskW5WUnn/7CzP5bxcWpMrFOHm5vz8Wf20fn6exymy8c5y5kkm9wQ@1VpmRzwep9q1yuOzcg65MuDPVH7n8VltNYfujQzURwn8dvKZz/xEIOFZWzqT0srV27dv8fv26vKKu8jB/c7ehqH48zYPXtyFXvDBqPl56ZOO8SwTKkpjvXl9A/3dWbqSFj2iwujoCrl4Ni51WEnGUYeyrYLSUVxF1XZjnam12sY6eGxsqTmlgKMSnuRMHgwGZ7JG8zAaGehWq3XP0yc49lLWAIiyvV6tnsm6d34mN0pNTLue295grpfbXlVlVX1X3NmBPDCLkgrecnosu16aXd/E/5Trmx2FPir@qSp6qsA49KypCkRQ1@FtfK2wHWVHQT/wwnTXNzV0UrxrcDUUtane3HA/5bpyo6g7HGxNBcox0Dj@kf6h//n/z//L18wHteUmhaq0w9bWVaU1MdW1DWUrsy3@qktAWUVeTa@ijpTW043Gk5XVlc21xuPmClvBL1tRds5qzfmdtZpOQYMOGmC1mMLaRQGmVY7lYklOozuVqhjixA7b7bLV7QpJOUgowwddUppBrdZ2Qj6OOnG1hkzAqFqZ2mTqzTXwNoWBxq2IRauzs3GhoLJKq7p8ndJvKoiVzG5kETNoHQRaSVdoRVO@lpd1r1Fsyjfy8nXrBoclK0WVNNL1tUplZY27lxWluL1R2i6VNjc2toqbW6CgbBQKeVYsbpXWtlbXt9fWNrbWN0C4qWqFMlwprgg4BYAjnFuViunrRgWFViUFeCgKDACB7qkzqdoyu5A90GUQb8@Z9fX1pXwJHuOHG3ulMVv6tIKfxgrUz1ZpK7OSaT5prGxvY3U1MeTTklTB5US@dinnZC4E2NY25ZvChQ/@2alJjf6406Qt5tVco7ix3swxqKwP484KoFHcXE2t8Njm8hFJt5VnMB7KFOF/b8mnjmrAHBj1bhZY27Vx36Xb6SyBZ0/3Wcs0YXhn2nZwPAyMQO32ldU2lyTfhE//SDdHpnk1Gl2Z4WfX8vUPH/QBfcadH375kx9@@T/@8Kuf/vCrn/zwq5//@vuf/wS@fwnfn/LnT//d9jr@/vr7f/m//fDnvwLPv4bvf4bvf/r19//69/iX3v8Gvv9XzO9vxDcWj38lgPXHv/7@Z3/x6@//@S/g@2/E9xfT3x/@9N/z//9b/KHzVz/86d/gj3j5yU@BSn//V7/E/5/91d//51/i///@v/79X/2rv//jf0uOP@OO/@ff/Dv@@3e//5O/@6d/8ne///2C35/c@vv9Pfy//0fwuT@e94Fzn3J9rs/3vxU@vws1olyAB4DT/uiHf/0HwKt/yt/@GbzBfxj0h@FLIoS//GH0AhD@lzmJ/ujX3//JX4Rvf5CMmAgDIH8IYX@eCPvDH375ez/8xf/wwy//7Idf/jHKodzadraezRXvONAFIq7fIx5G3LhPPIjIoyyxJalET/wRnmyJXOMVaX0Vh1g5/slwz0/LqGOys0/SOrxnPuXxYB@W/yRCz3AHVBFCV9cotAAqcwFD1/E1CI2hgkvWj58ktHqOyMqnJwwiQ@JYZIr4mCMq/DOfEsIcU1L4Uog4fKPMlsL0S3MI85g9gWDoIqmX3MFffAGfpzDeE8O@am2LVaUs26riUSYYsQrvFI5OeocOFY/FrkrP2FMcqKL3M6AQH5SzsfSevUds0b/Go7KaBOHfgcdTDoagIajvJPDKcJ9n8PxOxB9LBA//hZ6KbvwGAfCTYdwPXjMIJBOQiWUkHoMHs@ARpyYOljAephvjP4sACTgZCQiRycaHZGEWmchLCl8zM7mE@EyFZaIwRnlmkqAybAbgbYEJb2k6IZsLRWCwMHSqmEHonByD0NRskjAoTqBMJkkwTJksVEbKoHHcish0JbNCtjArn/sROFEGc8lxyydO75Wo5HG4EfYRVMKXJ8hQ3Chvgqhw3YoWE1hxYy0ErEoKHf/GVJrZMAegykkv/e5Td6wUsrKcLW7MnzxQcR4E4n7jlsvV74prmxI86X2EJ9GJM9GAt/F4cW0HPoCHVLvOoXMHnaCsbUi1mlgoYUWpdrJ3CglOD1mxVNBYo9C8Xtssra2vrZdWNzbWN0vFtY3ttY31rdVCsbBRWC@ViqDFbm9tb95Ita/ZWGNHRz/KgXucy@VLlEW1uL5ZmVQhIXlJNdIbuXY5uc75qFkiXmekyl6jQQPO7VzTdN8D@DDpgcQegBd8ADTO6zKxnnZwWBGrLmh7F@rrfAlGLq5vy0SmM9Npc8DSIPaRTvGs2VcACAjksBdohjd02anr0gl7T01jQYzdHj8tftdzff93iPNUdy540DMLD4kxhmHQcx23ivt9a9hbEOP1oI@Gwab3jwZhr98CBHEOlEd4Cj@e7brzImyy10cLSvkyNPnGxRqy@YboxwdfPD@NPU/36rvPpQ329PDVs6nHuoi0zl7s7Z@Gr5s8NEi6HoL4Zu/Fi@lX8cAhzhJb38xmNU2DH3xm6UNPbfldEKWoLVY15I1CaVMuZs8nJgxgrnO5m67VMosbMHJdkx@lYHiFJxWe8LMYh06bjTvE9Nubxc3tDdv1V7aK6fSpcWpIL9GAZbvILY8tH00sAeSVQxauLTzueTRY7AkP9EKnZ3V7IFmu3DACtKyrq3D26G0wVRROGb1lLV3H7@d@IAcz/hne7jHkeZDfTIg9G116DkPDPh5riLuzhrhoYnVYQdJQYpRK21vrW9urpa3s1vbW2jqMPtezxVIWhteb24VssVDcKsKgeruY3VrbXl0D2QSh69ubUgpkgNXJ50EsF2WZnpZj4NlQO3jIlqv1alKqbXaQadlYaass1Q49RltMXt06KzBIKEtoFbcyrsqlNbQXXC2yoizJOjNYan9/t7C/L8tP8QWnLncLstzGl/WtQmHzqSybFLIL8rMEiXr4treBc5yybOHLbn1/HyF8wJfSFsKQ5Qsewl/s4GUTojn4srqKAJgsfxuCKwBwl2O0RamG/KVQeLoryyOO3hb8Qbw6f1sjZPfwBQMw0T4P2YUwWf4iSAS6sSwf83giq@dBeet1WT7gL/U6gviSCr/OC/UVvtTpA4k8eAPOleUuOLoeDPtluQVO5F9ZNsBlTHTw64ML96M6Q12WJ7wcWBJZHlNs3biQ5fPAH/IBfJ4/13vDttnln4nHnwYEHUCQNR7t7be@@KLV7ba8SX3vi2MK@vLL5/qHychrdVsiYescPi6mgqCL/mT6Y2LQ@bluzw/6CoKcqaDzyblJGJ7r3wJm4tPFjPrnX2LQlxA0b85MAIRPHyK38PO0D8@neosHBR8Koue41ZIryLLYdDoKMa6epUeLNIhrhvYKvqI/JtlVRrnldkDtGG2pufXHoy15Y1Mur8BTfiyvghOaBiukC4zJ6TNZVhvbzcfy5rpcTj9@nEs/Kj5m8ua2XJY3N6HnVSs3KPYU9bqjjLPjagE88vkdbNDYBOEJ2oDoyU/N8VB7buJCuZHLvU18UFt5CzFxGwzuS3g16sPg4Qq1Gjq/M7CNPK8@BYWmUHFwG5CJr8vj1FiqtfWhDoOdp9ejclnEval0qw0E8Al/dnLy29pbucniOa9vFgCv145R2tzZaVx9aoJSUwUNaZLSq8XSFryhY3MtrtAs27o/XC5ulsqN0XIjV2wuLRU@dXfkH9cI@I0UlpyLtFAoQSB0SAy@uZyE4YOqqAqZKXhKMa630eq8kk5vltJpNV2BtEsyEFnQmJbksC6DqpBBGEJVbJcguWcOR9AlFyo3Mzl7F2Wgq4fmGZRDmckboDeBNx79PO/zBIbj2fJKa32n9k9mPv/dP5n3me@LH4lrghtFKXUjtfGYq7VtKXUt3Vzf7NSCHL9ik4meCYa87BFj3cyytJzGoqdXk2O8erXePa4H87f1XSmVW3XX3NTy8rKU2jmtyavyoXYeLtfU8rQqeIaLhri4pp2d7yxlfqu1nJxWexKsiQLqeckzcbdCG@/U4UsqW@tYFV3mpzK/5QcykaoAU6rgFLicQsFg2O4IV7V3zniBdr5L0ZILO7rujBwyVyu/RDVZ0ctcKWk0oXV@98qyr7dWczWyslCAx25uiC@MQ1r4llKOK5xASBi3DKGNKqBVr8ti8GGywcn2u813W@9evj58fbjPnhTKW@UtpPsZcEm2mC6moRKfQA9sHe9JqcEnd734nfNlJVUepFfX0quxajurpgIeV5D1lUaj2GSN1WazAcyG@MJ7tVp6XFzfyqyVi5tMTdVwT0lpE8mNLmj7udVUM8WBrG2q4KYp9FIxVcsL7@JmUU35Of4GSdZTvpTaevkep1yCu1@sErnyZPy9fLNzA/@1G9bY2bmhodONcODPzQ0Ph38qR/jGH9EnFjEeJwr/7ZhOO081v8vt8P8d/Nk95CWVN9ZlNfW@WgNWeHf@7jwlpbaZXKLay@TFGAhaUhe1rhWH/kx/xX@34q9EHiugRq6Eb/C6s8LWa0XGzJV8Pn@m/qgEKtn29sbWRkr6DVDsFuNUCA2ttTomjE1Ajs8x16p71ksdTdmc0GQLHC9HH/Gc7yfBDT@B9sZQfUN7RNTf4n5CpYt50cVYSb@Jn8fNM@grSeiy6CI41iEWxNWnIW2CYCu4wR73CKrStfQAYI2MIe27gZ@KJD3ADSD4qgTxsuyRP1Rx/qygSg8eCAHsDzV/eI7AMZHwzBUrEnQNQB693fYZnbSPK6d8Y6GO2yncAT@Jxp4wnsinw9C5Kkp7AjHfGMIrrMOxgNKsMMqRMMfC8ewf8GitUQdR2T94sQdpYCTdIcMpkVr2WngPBRVvqaOysB8BGuBh7FVBKYqOEQEceHJNQ@3j7kWDmjPLsCKGd8gAC2JlWTFLmGRZRyRs4GsTkiP4Dkg1HwDz3BVeArZyLrIVZRD4UCGAhFg66g7RoXtdIytqD09pbTRVdh3skVIwlO2wUrSJS8CCyuB3x1FCo98WZ@pXIzITtGIzC1Vb4XttlDCe8IkIdSOtDLP9Cq@qQUX6SjFAIXI9pfJd/9Ej492g0W9W1H51iM9Mpg9d9IVi8Sgrw2q/CuwxaFjNyrCRyVjNal/9SsF3vLoC@3Oh1vmqKBuU3KkCLmjQ5qvZjw0n953TzO43nAygPMqu/Lj6MatXC6iQZa1qMWtnv60WRTkgz2H1Y8ap6DvwRSPExD4m0EoyeiXhhUkuFLv6saE3UcOzIWEmsw@FATz9hp3JNFXI3IbA2YQV@9EjPWPXxhU7l1Mx1rvVx/uNITiamSq@lxV9Z/z4Y2ME6csKPKuQja0C8pBO0PomxB3wqwCNeZ1GqHMcSQEdA3r9anXlx49XfrxSXVr62Bjn@s0sJ3@5EHEDIj9G5CuxfWLKyo9VNkUSWkhW5IdW@aG24jM5a2UyQOTsIJaSY7jyYwgZZDIB1jcoL@lGq8DAFTlM7G3iJ9PT@c9kr053Cfh0Jcewjbs8IW3dNyxLROfbcweW2cbTNS0/S/dV6BQDw8QVexh4Nn78WAqyFttpIGcULi2T6TilQBctebiyTdc18vMk7pKv88RwIHPDoTTdnQCD9tWNWHMl0UQNzveMBkZBMXBduKlwicU3UYGwIekBcUh6YLwcShEkkpATImZVBEJtBRUEqVBOdPhZKHTqA8on1K3Dlg8ihKMBjXkOGlb2Q5VkE/CTBS5m7VB@4ICmIj2AQiAOWAaryWogyNijR0y87lRZsbSJfQFGw3gfMkWMNIMpZH4PTAEGYvkBeBTlIWUCuD3AENwkmMho7XfLSOzxVSBB5kOWb/XVaKuvMnJ8vsMd6aZyNLAuHjz4kKmuCYTgn4YmkB7Cbn6TEt19me0evjx6fbp3/LJ@Ar8wBt2KX0kTXPc2c9nTAC9xalkObXQz9OOi@c2XBmMKjr/wMGe8zbHNvnz9gpVKr55l8ShGIH2KT4lDh1oOIZk@HXXva67XzV9ZF1Y@eQ0tXrxHe@ro0ttccHcNokOdsx3tu4@23fs4nweduTg/LnFNTN/0fXGHVS64D5RO76ETCPq4kR5aobjzirYrBBbXZN@PhhNZ2jXiWV2LLnnscQCJ9HT7x5Anp/Yh4V1VNBIGjpa2twqFMitk0VEMHKXAsRo41gLHeuDYCBybgWMrcGwLRzGAXOSQYbC8uroROTcj51bk3A6da4XIGUFYK0XO1ci5FjnXI2eU21qY28YWwWWpgJrUdE0Pw4prW0EYTTIMyXMdwBSnPdcA0dJMTEi@NuMJ@W0lPTe3CyKjg/whRiqVNqJ3kD5B3KrCscpyPLI8Z/4mPKGvkvgwjxh2z/NAKu2N8XI@YDq1zHAfsSThUS6GbeqgDJhD0FKq@8D/plrm52t4k3K0lxghVIvhOyTHu2EgTZHul@TsMye4NC@YQyvNhcYPNWEhYWIbsQWSHMtyoqflENcSfnGoSyhgkaILYpR4DKyD5M7tIM9TbzQ3y9Xbs0wAnJvlDFIc7vq8VEgbhYBXg6TU/xO0apAf11NMqm1QA8RtwsQDUxWKB61Ur4tl@dff/@L/YL/@/me/Yj/8@a/@3//0P6P73@PPfwCdhZXCCD/9GSMLEPj5V4zsPcj2JEpE8VfL8g@/@CW8/k//lv3wk5/xoD/5Czm7FgKCEPSKUv78n@HPH@DP/yln18OIP/8jHhGTyNkbKaFaKRDrp3/NGOSGUEJgv/hLxuQMKBiK4LwGb@PN2LEMHEBIhga5mtPh/BfvZAMaF9SMDHDFWzF6y2AFqDHgno7X40ZtD9QZPpWJUtrQjR5uvRdero/6j4EqjOtrXeC3qzYoPWJKIg2l/31WZukMxsGJFTxfpspluCi/KLcchWLcjJwH7PBeJwGKbqwLMYHhrQT8TSOBia/hsIVGpEXOI4K@r/D67aADkQPOogu8JJFXkBqnZMRlpnSjWzDURabFboifz0IXmUlib3gxlmFC3ExVG@Qy7QNDxujEhnhS8jD7A6gSSBbSGwmLL0SF7DS4qOZEs9k73J9qMPhpgYp5EZdIYUZVJst3xEVKi/gqalyryfgcXxGhUSivNhPnP8yLLH/99deyFPMrIA95bYUgxArFRUYYVEwGlWJBpVgQ4MxhkqxZL5WmcKCOA@Vi8qwTniwmopLJIubClhPUA6IBY0E@IZrt2CO/V50FTRI5KexmgcdAFptV0U7OHJI5NSarMwkAZjJNdbou54MuzMSZraj5KZHaCZ9EbS2GlEgTaxREPWmaSmHNFbfn1Vwyw1tAF5uZe2ZUKvyOGeXumdHG@t0ZTVcrpk2AX0zfu8VOICZCCR8B4w0/leigsGv8BbBeJI4QY4@cigpDnroY8rSuXKbMubUW/PPB2cuJq2q92InMOIh55Q75whd7MnBhyOGiFhy7Gfu1iJ4YdvAr5buO65l@/FwXi@98d9J4spDhdh3o1bJ4BrQl7mFGAwN@7lyyXwl7NqGF4jGbMPRB0JxQqHmen1uONTw/B@XT7qgRAfFVM3A7cloyICG4YumVULU9HCgunmU/VO@GSfouT3ZqGRfK4UAEpiGTOoMBnWHaMPhiPbyR03c5SbCI/I5O0EhbQ4UOnOy5fbdrOi4eqoSpp8AfRLARIX0wIFyyTM8yI4aRGEQrRlZXRdKvPjsp@6qEd8oG6UtJAAliZJk3TWOkrDcnu/OF2fFkQX4nn4/vSRzfk9vx7VieP5zGmTxxtgefn5f1qhJBgIgRGqt3o5EV56jNoJNAJfTG26B5gnuj2CbrpzZiWoeodRFd6wB/ZMM3nzYeC8TfLKL/7RUYJN@7b/WRMnsyAXnTp8tbaYjmB0vuCkQ/UNXIojGWXcjaz@6Zlxjo0Agvy2QSXA7uaoeGORiYTnR/aAD4Dp5Hy6cZvidzqCoPnIOTd5llF6XFVfTsvG3a@sRsKyJmNgY3KPGxqbdJXt2v4CjoSOi5/ApwpZAtJlQxOn2EIpUXsIyevVTVxWzFo1gh99BiHGF4sJh@NHE3LZpxErTK10BcDyRoig4opGMhB5PBhJ9YZNNRYoEc5f0Pr8lXeJDTnQQBOvArcovZKFv1NvF5rIRFukePEMbVkkWmff9Bt@WCNj5Th59HortLSrMMYaJqUMsJ7WRRjVu31XiMKwKe5FrJ/VjyLqa7N8/FWI0Di0TY7ud1ITOQd3XbNgwlDpH73FpjrjMjE9APa8x1FvQq53MEapiSJN0Q796rcv1ClSxwHsDzEp5v4IkAYQx6zhkqKBvqtcGUF4X09UFMaxE@DQN10RgV1fg6YiyWFLhxIvcmzNNYmKcxk6eRyDNsAcksY5EkI5GlqAWsntuqwDY7wwXSGYNw5A6P28Q2fBxX93Dt9TptpctWlqUv02UQyGkzXd5TQCin2@nyM3L46fIJOS7S5a/AEbWt9Kd0OWgWGMGDV3I8QX8hwvHdSJd3FfVGGuLprEG@Wroc1inEecxfiSI3fHq1JVb93XBW1cT73VGpzDLkGB8eLhar0czStwD/FFWc@guBS1VWWqHIOABJdBqxHoPnA92GZrtXpqfM6z7KwdSUmN@I5lAgPFONTaogl4xIHqVT6aQw4ohhKE0@whMQRLlZno8RK86MzO5CR@QOHEqVnMyfqKeRPtBWKLwBkeOTOHaUPqivJAhegffDExMvwnMGnSA7wgiNAdQ5aCFR36dvKRTW9dQJsrz24zU0O0eAlZgLovBaIrAxmQ46HOqmlNnAHSSZhEJxtc@Kp8GPaJTIvVPJSCqIlrkgmLxFyVAwxBu/eltxYukQtYQIwsBGoclbWdgvkCzGoEjWxTRV3vgAhZjMadORbiay7TPhpHhc3GSpr1jUDQVpeZYkuZJiEhJreOrBSB/y3KN1GTwL4fOGr0HKMZ5gryCAWMowFy5f3c/Q312uvwcKdUCEqQzmKdbzu9JZ9frWXnYKczvKdrYCMTDLnqlzlaMwh4jkMDqIaea38dqMio/XNHMln2caQp/S9gOyhWOCO@g2PbbgsFBL8C6Tnhc4MXtRWkyoWY3EvtQCpUXDnAQcXvAQ06hot@PKCz6vijEE@2h4fHYFe8kKjlcewqMCeFMk563cGzlkXhW1bTqYK1q54KsOLlqJhechxzxB3JP9WmiiBR6H58fPDl@9@AY63c3NTXV2KQJbLaSN@nHp1mWCcNhSyuKRlrhzjmwneq43XDpz5FmTMvIAZUCndRvOfqKNq0KWxeT5VNuFdDxujKIC1kXUDPSEVEJVR8cu2xJ05XeDKSu6ABKot0DvLI3WcNUIuQMXdM7Pqfs6P0fjnPNz0Yth1YTLSL9JiVvCS5G9BrgS1kykcfkz58bhBMCoT1ujggk4cSIct0NJAZyDYZA6TDVyhlZg7IDzQ7RnMljLV1aLODtx0Al9CA80ylBKaziELa3jITI8FcbGiU8yrRT5LHFFBy9G8AeuQ0db03GhpLbjNQ1@MPVKaI@cK53MQHgudPZNDCNukBWsi7kOv7PA52lxcyZNIQe0yTKzq9GKT2kbhhwX1oCfeByafvgqJSKEyUYLaNyyzT6gdAK8O2c2@aUFtdLbt7pdYKS8uPCOG7ic6pA053Zyu8FJfin2RretdnCmvLAJo/scxDwwkFNJHMXos9IGaFPbWaBs9AXCopkMw@MWC2SkRbHguwmPTe7cysbSLikTNfksBh8V4S0p51izfEe85eHldpe6E6MzfT7Fp6bFoiXJgdjKZXD4nyROga3SOqWGNmoDRU7JwamA6ORmE7ptBIcUKng8Zll64JDgQQswZnDbGlBwHVTaaHlNDU1SHfaQrZYkusnCpcllni3A4Ct7CegQBkkRWW7dJwSM/LAtP8TFROlBCmUh5zVMH7Ayuul0@YiX2ZIAxxdUsCnzJhC8rMdeVmGo8WBOxkuKnAEoGVmVE5Agvlj9eMAl72xSEIogHj7XFNv0PIeiSZcgShjdVCzMiCu3GPaSZS@aDybsenEwFTfU7Aj7NX69V1Z@jRZYZZ4J9R0aHvqKorsyLbtzxcBckx5oJ81WaMtxJ9HRyB4mDtFYspzbEKAehTgU5QyZfz30y/AFHLIBSCATWSwoRBv1TtyIImhHjedXFJqVWJeiFOPYIIIdHwRKB@iZlR@i1eojSEhdLPR36jy1qVBJpAfk/IFDltxyTpMpqbA6RkhJELw20T@0fZXI4D0QXLccY6/ni1uFjW2yn2ZOdpjtN7ab2RWjKjNzaOlO3x95V@2Lrtu7BGWBDT60xsbk47eMra8x3GBSesT36Bc3qnnahr9J51hsF2hzR3BIBp30cCYzRtt@8UyONGPhhqPKEm7Oh08Wf8pyZYZL2Uo/4EJuRN1vbDSrTrVQ6TecZsXJZNRhpjrMFDMKejwqqhWQtHzapTFsklVkfoW9DEwX8ZBXnFt1O@zIdYyem/YZ3REaX9OjfWRBA@rrg3h7uoRRh@vFfTrIT3o/0RBnvejqrKmUlhvEG04GJorG0OrTxguW8efBaGOtMhuOJXzwAE2UK0I3jRfgWhqMWrZlgAwieqKKgeaK5bIwujcY8i0IKPSzuCfHBXogBYMrQajhDiYiscWjnAdl2YmBrCnYd6nZ@8QMYrWAJ8/xSH4PovEonLyJ6AxAU9ejcqzQ/cJ0wn4G90moFbQiZ0tBWLCjAuMj39C@hnNQ/2gXBDx2mIhKNsZMFRa95Nuw0KiAVLVamgc9@DDqD6h/1zi@giJ439D5QLe8MKXmj/DGMoUVkRhWgDTWADpucF/eJSiW8aoJ6gInFmhxG8uD8I7o0GhA2NDxrkWQjbi4g/DaLqV5wC@0UqAT5BNXHA2RloqhiqoGwuEpa@lBusxonqECXtTlVGKhHyAUy7oguA/BfX3YWxDcQ9gjf1GwB8F4zdWCYAuCuc3J/HAXwrkmtSDCEGfRgF3Ph@75ULdshRtMo6n1DRfYCstkAsKGLMB4xfD6SKZnwvScLfHa4cyWYC9on8RWPAKytCIaD75H3EKheBSHwvkilienCbtmd2YmJp@AxOeUE4hdzF9dScBnMQSg/YEoZbPhQea8tsOCJvhHg26ni7UNxFplnz7dhplgxCT/FZsB9/EawnnOWAk5tSI4/BaeqF55oo8i0fw0wjQ/Lt0CHTQqR9AoS5EI4W0ratcdC/RFSKqilhN545BSZY8jn4bfZOVQekR05M3ibjqWZrgHR5zUIrOsFTmN@1NVR76HlDr0yK1IWOA@LL0yQ04/jJ1Lxq5B7JCaU3xmJHhGtNLPLez9SpMC/KhRE20qXNAaoBrWBIJz0NN5vcZlAge2nC5zf7wzyEoCsxYA4/sVzwHAcAdwwJ4tEONBn2g5Grf5ATlfKK1laQqfR7mJyBQIq/vQ6R@gcSHhRJc9wmsUkiKJzSHNTPSw3Eiv2nSTmyoel/TzC9fgRmPpx2nEkc3yE3HdY@gly6zAwo0xFXZztxz67ShzHVVfQt/xlcWyIqj0gBPvw4I3Cwh9J5Mli1BqsgTFEQWSDHd0SbTJc36nFC1dnAc@wbQWb9sLNTDEqpIMR5w5wCAAFOV4qqzQuWqR6BS7W8@HgXKTjbQwvL2IcwWo7BUpLs5xOLdPnXfcN9yaQxSJh6ClIGqYXoCZ1Ql0W1CDg3SacY7VzImM9IQ23XXdthIoTEJhIAiBBTREyvLtQqFaxdXLKHvITii9rCusqIN@twI@S8KL@hXwQOVT8CYisdKlZlPBZhPTbyyfLteicOyNIKtgdQcng7j0YeVpf4wdqkAP5iYKJD7u@aKdwULOU0@cEA/yru7gxBsdFEZD6x0Z/cOKwDg1GGhH@4epDm7mzDLwPdJi9/B1fOhiVSwNdeKw0oNZJrUSYrOzI2M20eEbv0kt5Ue@R5dCm84lKNWtiZRipsOvVijjFaW5LZyIxRtGhTSheW@a5AE2gZrC3DTHvFLELaS4S1tWJb7njyaFihKeEEHz8rZ52Qatn1vED1x/TL8TGCwUtNFg6FKIyIj2BrJP1qdov3qBVmnFiEGgs0NwojgKrt9w3wmfi8oVuYJUxNMv1BiIBqYkgSufyTLWHyIq5usaTcnXTN3oIRLIe5/4cAqqizj5RvKDqse9bEgKXBwEp82teAc0N4dZkHbiT@gdio/vRXRwH5pCRL4X4xSJJlwxxHbdATI5TrVh@h0gACf8g5PTZ3vHx5o4H5mvCOAqAp8nRhMM2hAobhAW06S4GoDbMXmlPMDCImyeXzUCTvKXaITZCjJhU7hCcnJa4X5PXoJckd5mihHGV3l0IgktJ4s3H2lZEFbTA9CjkHZRMiWWLBckCyLHSPHgTmrohoGGti/NvgsY79K110VOiwcROdCJFAnyz4T5@w3Msxkiz8NzM@G5RLjGwzlSUSzN6HlRpHI8kpy6juLdMDmKlp3Jq8qg0AevaPeO5noxvCu3xfU1GKRZUeRaWJWcK8OAnURALhbybk7t85ClRJqQwcPwBg8X/F0SNR9imYj7JJk/PiVRQSbZuAqTkCku1RzL5rdaRyEkYRluW@HJsb6J7XijFBMiQpzkQEzgFb/YbGvVCEqmGEgcajNybeeJrIkpqcfKNBoqvwh3umHNaSMxKlGeGSLcmHoSyIeCl2IgCCYyGgtabi1IPBGJJzGwGGspyFYKdmInGzgUbbqJV3Ha/BP@BI09iVwQLzU/8AHHfMwLz1eykgQiobskzydTUpoMvZHJPUWhbulForwn0xDnC4lXLo5AjR7d5BzkafL1to47ctpLoZyIC4pAUszQPQwRlI4iFAP2XVSFGHgj/Sa/In2h90ErtM0xq6NOrdOZSVJiMRPvXvbx0DE83JL5o8HAtsS@OXZFy2XiRKHSOi72RBBjSoMmHaABDo@fRZdYfIREGjtEyFdoxxEF@HgbN93iyvCaOBCtHQtADjWp7kz4BbO4zazElxRNNvL5fex07XwMCV5zvPWEl/ZqUrBwy4va4e3bGYIKBAV3PX4budspS9KPRpZxsfsFKxUKm8XCajFGsmCquqCtrsUvEw8DSoViobBeXJOkXXcw4aYjiqEirLUcAsyyF9jRvwHeNC/xGjepDj0GRcQTMX3TuzTbmiQdm22aA26NiCLIynivO51SQfvo0Qd0KzxPCG869rP8OmPgMHxi/8zPBjDIcDkr4RrtwPT61pCv5LqX/EL7YF2649q2e0UT0bgkzOmBifrmEIiyorIkSrTvX@BCugttxwdq6OK2Wb3lXtI5HYIMoKdaeLwRLbBKuEkVIcQz41dVxjCB/Axbt/rITnMQwF0sEQUCBKBo7ZFh3oqDREh8Jg7BNbpt1xjhyQd6UDN5kH4utRVo7qZngfSNCEy1QsliuEMFnz4/OGEnh/unb@vHewzcR8eHbw6e7T1jT79hp8/32O7h0Td0@it7fvgCpMsJq796Br6vTo8Pnr4@PQQPuX4CKWUKkOqvvmF7Xx8d752csMNjdvDy6MUBQAPwx/VXpwd7J1l28Gr3xWvorL/IMoDAXh2eshcHLw9OIdrpYZZyDZJJUTp2uM9e7h3vPofX@tODFwen31CO@wenrzCzfcitzo7qx6cHu69f1I/Z0evjo8OTPYYFk54dnOy@qB@83HumQf6QJ9t7s/fqlJ08r794MVXQw7ev9o4R@UQpn@4BlvWnL/YoJyrns4Pjvd1TLFDk2gXiAYIvsuzkaG/3AB17X@9BcerH32QF0JO9H72GSBDIntVf1r@AwknKHVSBetl9fbz3EpEGSpy8fnpyenD6@nSPfXF4@IxofbJ3/OZgd@@kwqQXhydEsNcne1mGV75Q1gADqAXh4H76@uSA6Hbw6hT6jNdHpweHr1So5LdAGMCyDkmfEYEPX/HSApEOj79BqEgHqoAse/t8D/yPkaZErTpS4QSotnsajwYZAhFP48Vkr/a@eHHwxd6r3T0MPkQwbw9O9lSosIMTjAAwMd@3dcj0NZUa6wnw4k5gVing3CxVJzvYZ/Vnbw4QcxEbOODkQHALkW33uaA5tOW8NHfJ7dYFvNlVPjEVcvshPLuHz/ZA4@Pn8smR/2vodLaSi3eJMOhowkB4Faug1Fedt83WqHuOV8zj0DxMxlew@343i6dbqnhFz5l0261yfKGcEqRS5@dv6ucwzj05P1ez90mZQOOuFGKX@22xVFFG29XbNMxPzC3FCVV7JM7SyfKDLeJzLY/CyQeV5fNtUyRD4xAEHEwTiUOfAFgbJSNZjegOi2VJS8zJuSI6kWx6sihY3nR9@HE@RS@8b4h5gHDmdgv5PI5hCQ08WY6F@EMmdOiaOHmN7ACsDmWp@aZ50VUK8exwyC8mqNQgDcUdwjCwq6h3JG@Z3ankuen0hCza8pCyEhy3ExyDw@/3xTdBMibqRfOoZAqf2qOHGmBDGYFSqPKsyFBIWJ8oj3hy3L/N5wrVSnhUCx239rL@9cFbHMwVSmuVKf/noT9vW2jVh2cHQn/XoHRNejxv8gjQwCwcfgFJrAlfUs3nY2lAKyN9MoyMZwH1MNKV1YY@FbvqnkndOp5AxI9jiKeHztizxnHsQQx/cVx/@fT1/j5ITsR2bWt9c6MiiRONvOHXWf78BvOhU3eRuqBFX1mgplFQrJXsgt6zP3MYYez0RKw9jIhnlAeVRp54v3G4M5nrCPz8Mj4NhMX18QQnBw8xk/EQJk/mN3gvSQG/zm2ZggGURFFVLE1fH5OGr4OqRDxg8F3I9oRqbYw/CDts/kETDwskGEiwmNkfDCfAuTC4ILkn7wcGnTS2IbMtjKLJAR8P9MAGiRMGZSZZuaKNI70J3o7VIui1WNHYXqnaKSUgsTSNRXAIHh1pCVkcuX7QgrmnBT5fC34D5zfi8EUMwqO06sMTION@mDIXHI7I55xFwxCQm7UqVNGjR2FOOwwnUlWBFJ//Tx7NF28NhAo3aGBTgAPLo5DOYQhNQj9Jq@yacyqemoJwKoJjxTtw7rziCCiV4MgZ8R6c0Mc4rOjAPvK6CvOQgijfBFFCcibI9DvRg@D/N6TJHPg7MOAE6BG1SA5bzsi8JyUJKqcVjF6JKNZVYDEWM1OLqBn3@iYCcxOvmF5YMGGGN@YLS0ACUTuTwOMbfmSrMocAyOQ4rxFvv3hAAjXing4jpyfUdh/wlX7PMfoDJTjwNOgqZuA2s6RzZQMTOXxR@RJ@gcWye4Hn1z2hfbQkM3DABVKsNWEPfZnDyBRJ5mCh8ys06RG2cmJNJEMxaOEROxVE0woa/1hYGEW9TDsIvQFVdPFhquFyCJ7ZmBD4wQpIIEDI9ileYEE2yLOGiM4tN1rS0yw/E704nkIOIpD6ZXZK5s@@3qExM3ZFwlYZjaIxS4TzsC3OxGyZwyvsLmwOnWy0I2hMeUhm4piJmIsM1YhA@KoaUJ062asQe5qmRH4NsX/tXDh4PYfJp7iCGFrihM34FneNvdTpsE37fuWWo8wzSNZaMv8Dh@zWDb5eiVNzNHKHXHCk/9CPKAIa5xVql9APRVTSjQv0lAMeta5y1hgelFdOlDw4MxLGDHQi8Dyl/2bhgAB5ZcoGlslnTjiJVOYdWfVhoL6gi7fd0PUNusQ8cxUKBciBDxrMCjUIUUa9CY00Z1sb4ZfYtoDGp2XQnK6utJY@6utOR@9b9oSsTj@4PSfvOyN/gDfXy7KcnA3Eg1bQBB1wH5rsreW03SufPYXmgBNJJ69enxwlJ/5iM1@7fOaLsS8hD/aUcpZmwHdwT4rvdoZQNWaFTcSdTl403UPzhGKmhaa1JuiBG388YiDItx9qxl@8es2@MB3TA33wiGwu2QvLMB0QH6BMkRWm3@OSBqPvY@4nIne2j7oLzexUmGnRpE44tyeJDAS0LLKWAk0REPbEsdU4Nz8BVo/NCWqzBY7K1Q4mlXruQOy2wElTVDb5FGdnZGclPBv77cHpcxyM84E5zc1AtxbM9eFcIled@nyyFgrj6c5wAkSRpidvAO275m40RpstAKK0mJw0qOvjrT5tnPazfSgqXsglpAD1INBUTesSD@Olabj71BHZ2Ypps4huFbF/NcuPBw5ER6L2pKj2sngmu5Zl69vs1ETeZUe2bsAIi52MMPnqKuiBT11/iFFf1hkrlIrFYq64ilO0r0/qGjUE/AYntErSwcujw@NTIKQ4gihgjLDPROLToajcGgvIkcOjUaH071EgB/FBYpbeE/FQBQ/OSZArfMVCLstQ94aO071QQj@pDtOULE7Jux4dzIq7bYCFEs0RcvWvUPjypRHKKQY9S0fDisNdedcS4km7JSnBe8TNBr6ycT30PSUmPxAA5pj8IJVHI4O2OFYI6qRv9kPsrWHQu@s8gjR9pmxIMD6XCsyRzqZRSwLqqXE4bRNtJHw8nanvXxoeyBb9ElgOTViCLUfAMySb1LA0esuyLWgDgJfRc7HD4eIqqAiagoifOCtRjYdnGWKHRLjMOQ0KWlfb7YdROVaSFG62E/4Df2K4LNWFYTaOtPyBabbpJKrRgB@1hOEatHIbeg6@Da8cncEkpQpkN@mBsMEj70D2jWzcm497KVu8zqWgNMBVwfbN0x4O6zkgKNHJkBopnoirzBlhZxmu86pU7TowBKZVkRALNlICiEEWF6UAK6hvYghyEbtkcbuPTfU9vc8SE9Jhj/4gGYCw@KqumQwIwGPZhXMmAmfSaojA1BbOABm@D4m7E3NgyRcsL9qd4qY0hZcRCjdRQ2LuW3hEOZ8bcFnXxV@MrAUU42uEJq0RzmwMxds3iwBvOmZxNibECg9oi8UszYGZmwtzdT7MnIApFisPnEvaEIepiC14KfhpGy7IRyREVPwv3ED00rY92@ULTGHpu7bbwnMxQVJAbviYZKOKjXvTCCxB6Hgo36SZPM9zJyiSQF3sbQp0F7YD7cOssZ1gxqJ25vCKEgFV3pZoTxijvouaEznxR7QocsqJw0FR65g6HRTR474guxGsLEAKH7nMopaJljjx@CLnZJJ@IklxKolALpmklUhSkqKd4FO1iylQ9OMzWbJALyGrJKoBVg0rqCD19TEf3RRogx9N0@CR3Ikdh6WmYBCM2DBYuGcQozel6AiMxLI9zyN4JRM8sviWl2U6UrSQPE9qHJjukRigWInwCR2z4iiiQKogA72Ex2uoATKiXDuUxIlJqrDAPEBKFNvDvVpKPBe1zFIDna8aYiwfO7Z41g2iAa7Sy/C3whSRQS6OLI@ExxYIUQiEp6MtGjCU5dUSyMGCFPXM9BYTcFCDEpffZDLGuwFFSbSrQHKHMLlzRnYDKPTn4Cgnie@v9kGv477Yo8REwwkqfHhMvFDyzDEMz2iNmUBQ/xPOWAtPfmZEKD0E8o0o52bQayRLsTD2dFcyL06sVwmpcFvkgNghnRZGXtzbEOlwDgHlHY8eI90LnCQWpAu64LTPSUZaijWkzeSuYXEJlSRbTOjytNk5AjhZ5QFy2alSSbGjYkQJp7sRKdFzJphEib3hNTjsIT8omANSpUQqpP@iCkdzx3jDXhivyOOJal/EESGsoN5vY4swclDvt7EFjxyr9tvZIjgrOiQtpZ/mi0RNcBKgUaIYMdCcUlwGBQHjeKzxVCxCaNKMnxVj2socbGNSVcx1SjOqUkgicTRcMg96jHnFiNvHkuwIxGuEtdGMSgt9nHFhtsMTL0TpwyFSTU52Cbw2pw96wkIHOVAdNVW8kiRMABKbT4KJMXOf227SiUFpPmChMSieitrtJXf3JsAGvUpBnVUog9ORIuR35iKfmz2lKhpilWfv3wmtywTWaPDkem2MLUtzVnylO7DKxLBKli5WQ0kSL4CUuxek3D0g5WOQRMNehf6SnCkPzwE27wJxdjYLgx7vYCAlYICkbVs4iY3j4Ct9chfMJVC2UmRTp3OrsjBBpCffBePxNAw6d70XrsYJz56Os24fTc@dPvVsIWWTvDIHoxCr1CxaWUSLpDaNd0W8QFWisa120epZ4UggdXdN83MiRGI0Je6Fi0Cp5KlFIbCo/RcX0C8bq9Zke@CIJ6ZhQFuWPrM5aEgIPsPEt4qFCWKCLDkOFQFJQtweOi38aLQ6fboEHii/MJl6Z0me8Amf2KRTEYrGJVaC44IhXCScgt4qkG/zhmd35p@am//AHYCO05mLAMXv4zw@n5SaEumRajo1tL5XXza3P5stV1xvmzr77f6N/NFM0UtQdNyYDo3aMa9E738bZFGWoAZ@C02@EfDIAiQfzkUSF9p1MbnFnFG/ZXrSfZo6T6Hhg4@RFnOuJKVSrG7AkFmcPEQ3QNHxyKbIEtVgZASfjQa4XuNz405s3DhHZnIGno6L98ZTbE3GLGiOtm/qjjiKSHSYXQ/XL8K4WTweHTd3UQ6WYwChfTM2/fme3/nRNkUIWiTfQtbK/LpHrqZ77TkW2SgngRbXNZVJckzLfRcoOKFWQ7HK04pKwDu4GLrCNXOhL4Firs6fAruP9nSbQgRMvChLMeCdAn07j5YXE3M0CEkZVs09SDlP3Qpnue@hbk3uq279N6DkdIVKMbfQHkQHW75TqE0P8unC2@Dg6/6co1venO7vJw48aU2CUUHf9NYLhQIegjNzux0uUOAqseXmk7HzOCeeH1x96b1p5TFp8j67udfZIQ4QFWPj0gTyCS5NjKC/iR2nhfM5Du7K@eDzmPwEnjYjM04rNG5/c0rMRyCReGaZvccCYvnes@C6aVAc@ZBBQAnszSA1qqGXcmAmB@RBjw6eqBOapBEwGjeLXQu48FGtXUsPxBWPNM@H1/Go19E2RPm5adtulr11Pbu9JPPdockE@/vxBAUeBU0JeePx6XqILDMvLTt2RQZGQdxc29Rst8vvWML7c/nsJ@1l8swBrqQp2I8dm9298UCRG@9kYEwocgaLmWFyE7f3dGXoomRaQr8bLD@QDNC@V@y@PlAMotN0ZOgDxV6qyAUYreIlmtw6GOdTdqHIaMyhJKKo/FwYTrO7YyNR56OrfXAtR4GiY7CE2@Vo6zdVL5VkQfSQuPLZuNhBGhY4DIETHoF4vxQ3FTx06rf/4Ow2zhzg5kaa4w23xMbOG4uXI5iMx5bFLoedDjQvPhNfC44aC8CRqMwVyUoBSSMq1jO/HYE@o6Q7fpofYIemNicTx0gg0ig1syw9Gna20gDhdyqjFLRA0fyAnmg28VUOmvX@iO5JieQZTcOhAcWs3MEE55hAkh4a1W@vlHq9zpYHmQyr15@CI5dj9ad19gw9nj5lz@D9Kb4/qpbW1yvccu6Zeg2eTwPPG/YUYFAXhHeyPYNXCKOrlnAohVW8nK8uZyvL59WdWsXPN@pPm/l8F1x/9/s/@bt/@if5unj5Hl@e0kvjXRhJ07T8snG9/Oimgu@NZ830cquxPGimuxXkMhT3rz1ft/XYNjHN@Ae5FzfYOW@oDDRatVpNs/SnT9x1NoycXuTESwyi5Lo96OmUnBGEWjVdTz96BK6davrHaRVP7hD@euj/EfyZirKc1ouJtLR8XD/ZPTiI3xMU3j/aQU0TF9x1YZxmOb4FhXqfClbPcw2maayZY@9D9NCg@5xHTKLI0mgxypH5TiAZlI6s78lKlTLm5qdkYMTtnrg1Wt/vknlRYKBEYWQMhoketsvcdI5gZEDgYfwK35Sq8OaGxQd00datmmsUN9abuVQqRTmTde65QWKOchtEVxUbMWNZsnTjJ@oNoMlA2REaotxgABCJkUo9NACPR4Y4x8GhuyGxwHReYTqVjh2NwQAlk98q@CC8ipeRtiF2lmEPS9hBZz6i7daoG0zua7gHCIQ3oLNrRrfzyvzS2UnsMsDYRcB44sn0LfHhKbvRPfF0TXwA0Jg6iWEaICcejO6Jg6qijME7qBuzTPVe3NbD1oKVJbHj3rUnXRsvz6RNE/4VSCegvCoqy3aCUxExB56yZXZw4ZO3aF5h0aY9UgxN3AvrGLi6AGqBY@MhulzhC65NBg0S2gNqOOIcjg7u@VZsh28VcDvgVPGK@@B6aGLDDB3uxBkKF9XoiBiePpADKwPQXQc8JlIV3iMzW2IPNPIWBhoPZg0uB6pISQt6gtMGDbToKzaDw/xV0ZJkaiuhyQ5olX0cguKkCBAFY2p04iyIhgl7bzvv510bTVaKlCXPpsQtkUFihdlYYuGVsuObfmWVlwbPp3X0oSDvwPV9SxiqiGoiKxy@S9gDqGdpiWcmuCV@sfbKIGxR8fIFrGSOgc9xHoyfOQK5QyEFFyQiovEmWh5yu7hUwh6XbldHkdsyh5bBt0rx3JcCWTyg40DQl5@bsjAjGDxwc9CggimHMyZ2oQpLUKrqCA7RCXclY/vvhaq3TjQLTIw4vsGpLYNGyBxh7ZxFRIoghpxAAJJEETjS5JSg4IMEY9pm1xom0mT5pmuxv5SX4iYgPTby92TxGKPuFGXRNii42ToUCe8FvQMjbBS8QRgI2i1uXT2f94LCYK/GbbHClLxIdHDG1ix/hPIoQCeONbRgIB8232yyhqhzxb7O8jkf8zqJWJVFtXBrDgRcoMjlxcr/19619LZtBOGz@StoCrUkVoqkpGiQpg3g3HJoC6S9yYVES5QrQBYFLdXECPTfO899UFtbNtzUKXKwQZHc1@zuzDfD3W9pJz9lINqiKZP@GM/3bUgD1GljGjgtPAyy9wYwDm7fkpOOaoiXu4shwYHy1vGiNd1Hzqv/N8sNuvJyi1SzMPngLRwHYKPdYvJLeGM9c@jGZhmdgR9KBeqofpe0f2m7WwHy50XqYlH8I@FdobYejaK06dLDfUJKGyUsG7f9vmwk1fa61H@Eqftt5m74pAwOHQ/pbLpC7CBPT9iYgzXVfJmaoTPUn3vlkBAKBrsyXXtHRE7mtVigeHCtO2pz1zn72NBQH161vLZZkAUujfEzp7yIe0je89f7R4S0pxDO@a6u3tWPj@kpdke1WS7sTTp2HnBBATBYIELRHcgVXI7pCOtHcgtQDyxBEfBOlcKUcJ0kjDzEw8x@Nldvq4@dYe8iu8h6o@9fdTPyky0Oa80MeEatWYkrqrfoJZTie4IllhVyf5WswreXy/kcEIccngBJpTT7aCLZjjFC/smqO9MnU5uREi8zT5ebPnQi3RBZ0/VmW1xdF3T5S/X7trh5B0aIfv665v78DfN7D8YID1GlJ@95jp7PAWpke/ST3Zg4qokUMi8A@cxqggZ1yVQJFi5EBFAeCIDLtO03YWM9Mfjt59iFRc9kN6FTp4xQDK8NnzIn4JRcANyeAH7ahO/B2BQXxhCfHV/SI3YImgASH@hOHu8up2Cov0rfYJqA0s8xqtHA61BpnKqXrmCADtXlur0pFe98nNram6k4NvXsz8n1blUvpWUHzdJ2YaJeyqLY4Qkj0kxkEUQ2vOVPuAHqR3pI9MqK0TFk2JSd1w7Md7yEWep8GVJUTgrihGkunv@o4qb2U9jRgQZxVZjB/fl3ND6G@9e39A2j@zfqaiDBOpK4ed1B7UWZe@4GMw5aO5vaVp8GzgfWA4SC1cg3qJNZNe/9PsYeRgp4Uia2cz@Hz/4lO7l8B0U2cVJSv1SWUbMOc74@7R/upcM@fS3wvVoYKZTYVNe62lLcCc959Y55hhmEO8j/a4f1Ds8tQH@eqHR/po9dToOJFoBD3RjnidOCGLLMfi9QW30w4iMJUjkbYUBjOWceaSXa@ojaYKcE3uQ6N0G2Iibb0oh6gywOjGfPwoiDR11FbxYB0aswpuaqVMW6OcMmH4MxqucsmNY1xJQ@ZE@dAXWYNeKE22Fwp6DKQ0GNHiYorldMTvzk0cQUCiCU0j5JYsPXqg7ZMOrPdcsVcKCXSHCnFgg38ogAXfqu6VWsmR10oCL7VwqG8/T8CtRiiIV51UDh7rHXww6kaXBD2UAcb6nZbcsfABEDukrgDyAvainaHxdEQACyDhL7EjFBoDRI3jYaIdxk6aDVTeTL7ICXEnVGL0ddKuSIkpLg3Ix7w3tWg/gpZnFAc4EGhSBHnk6EKuRu60e27h/C0kH7oiFp0MguKM3qOd9scMvuXVHqQUuPyEoh@7SbPjBATbGS52yDMM4zaCUnUAVGGrhgCwqj1N9KgNeU0IyNbpnhcK4j/mD/UAPdTyn@rTI2RMlvR4AFCENFB4jPMFfpYEEItJSQJmj7G9MGUdsN89FSHFQjuEiiDUayWvCRmOpoQMj2CllpozFFgtpeVDEaNdUIUdqKJks7vL@3WNGno3KGgXAbpTJdLx4sYYdBW9misVpMiWKzDNSV35yzs1TqRiHrBsaIOvqBoLgegTAu1qycm0MXlBDeJMGLSYFpYlHfJhp/4BfkDTc7z@JABNWrwyEuQjNwct@treTj0qGkt8kHG3RVNagESCZ8AJ2SPLraJPcVaFOedwxSCuh9OaP0Xj1x7FC1ROnxsci2@OWIbbFve27MAKMNaH2Yj58ZfYhCxtmfNPdplk7Y/lKYAv7xAMVzu4ra0oWBtjc1rxztukUepn5majJfr93nR/Tj2CYV8zmY4x3uxr@pIQvciE@nz3ly5kSGXIr7GUx10rl4UYXgYmJVmp6ZpHZ@WUqOmef@Kv8YSWohhE0nkB0tLyLOFvx0Vc2YAQwXAWJwgNaVkl87YrcIHSJOOMafQqRysmA@8oXMZG5Bmk@kWGmD1IcawRjr7baoj4JY7pMc725P18gGi2cNNMaheZbgoZn3hWTH4LL8aFzWyimmnTt4lrc2gC1ePDCPz4vTXIAW8slszTOcqBTAJ5cDRAwdtLrp@cF80Vr@J7eHw76v8OWpGob8ycOX3Ip/FoKY3IGYWRTEuBck1QwDb5TOvk/qAabtmjzkXGAPl1eF5cG80fKqaHmmRIbh1L0niSsqFm9Hiq0/VJLCDlQpkOKP0YJQ1/KcnmYyt6dp53BCc387M/ziqxn@P5vhvwE)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/~alecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
158 [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://github.com/Property404/hdbf),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
166 [yash](https://osdn.net/projects/yash/releases/),
167 [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef/releases/tag/3.10),
169 [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/),
171 [Agena](https://github.com/stasoid/Agena-2.9.2),
173 [Brat](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brat),
175 [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr)</sup>

### Explanation

Whispers is a language made by PPCGer Caird Coinheringaahing. Whispers only 
recognises lines that match certain regexes (all the regexes start with either `>{space}` or `>>{space}` where `{space}` is a literal space).

The only lines beginning `>{space}` were in the GHC Haskell and the Curry/Hugs. The one In the Curry/Hugs is still there because the rest of the regex doesn't match. The one in the GHC Haskell is now gone as refactored it before I checked whether it was necessary to. So the GHC haskell now looks like this

```
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1
>y#a=128
>x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
```

The `where` clause of the `Num` instance has been made single line and the definition of `g` has been brought onto the same line as the declaration of `B`.

The Whispers is just before the TRANSCRIPT inside the Haskell language family comments

```
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-sss
```

The only lines of this that Whispers see are the

```
> 176
>> Output 1
```

The `> 176` sets the value of "line 1" to 176 because it is the first valid line.  The `>> Output 1` is a command to output the value of "line 1".

Comment: **Over 9000 bytes!!!**

Answer (score 6):

## 188. [Zilog Z80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80) boot image (ZEMU), 9346 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bcyPNkhj2TMj/wC81DX4DgLg2QIAAQWAGvA05wyE5vAxnPpIfpgE0gCYb3T3dDRIYDr84sh1rrVYP0mqtWGktnbMrO7wPivCGww9WaCMcYb0qNvQbvn1ybDji/IPjzKzqCy7kzHznHFmOEEig65KVVZWVlZWVdemW4vR/85softihqY97uukyV3Vc1rG1G9XOsPUxe65oTjFfiEQQqmH3hgPVcJ3VSJTJjGlGW@uAn7nmtWpon1QbwvOMWbbZs5UBc/uKy1SnrViqw8yhaw1dZnbnJyswtjUwr7Q0phxoRg/AXNW2bNWl@GXGTg1dGbQ6ylRMcSpDy4Z4h22q@ufBZ5e1zcFAMToOQJYYe23ajorwbdVxTEy@wthoS21PIS0DqGJr5l5j/8VUVIWxF1BExdLVEVNajmsrbVczDaRJjh3vnx4fTqWQZfb2ZHt7OjTPXqVNg20P29fTUQV2ajuKrkzjX2aNoWvuutPhRdboqYbC8plKJj8dWWLrtjKTZIXZqtLparqagQZhadZXdUu1GYawrmmzXSiSXs6Vc81GkDLTxrTlIHIabYXphYI7VZ98Dghv2n3VgBLmpiNlP3IqIu9HdDTKQLHHLO70TRv4yGZDR@2wW9PuAHMZ@jiRgvRs9Im1FEctLSOCgo/g2jBvDWAi14SmbY1dlRmmkabECLjM5L3mNGPlixjaONidDi@x/N502AowWvu6O9uW@TI7Mq3xdGiFvdb25rFzIcc7wobZgdaYipPZoQJBlE2Y8NQ9D22zM2xj13H7KqTE7oat6UTa0Px1ZolOnkEHi1L7czBAfWwO1HBuDjNUIK9jqW2tq7U5W6gjVzUcyNDJMA2KcKvpOuuoOiQIsLdTzDGxcYKglq70M@1MBNkKc2GDa51prG1ZjEcxXYMibefKTMW6s08Qr/cdNrIGzNEGEO22zW5XVdkn1epD8kjHjDD4tK2pavm@RRVgDNUjjWpBd0bSmNj7gU4ehW5txQK@dwQNXG0AwkpzYw5TFUdDcQhJHNXoEFUtX1CaTJlgWHajQXeFqg9twu2oNnUYwgudy1YBpeKLqvitrbku8TxrsENVsdmJraqJSaE5kSVkZmIOLlYkQ426thbbOtiOQePyFBnFgsa0CydvXkYUlqmxxWYVvjVJqka29jfZ3eIFurmMBAaw7LiSYLUfmZO9uFDhO5Jb2Z59HwGsEaCKzrKm5WaVtAUFTLtQwKyCTnSlb/IZSw9lzNam2iLEchyqA60BooO9TVHN2kPbxnEgIKpyDZXWTaMH9ITK2kMD6WGwUg6aoG2CGE8x9QaoBnKT2gh6NVL4pK9BoznYJKFuwUczIiiMZ8DGgqJevo6pDwkOUjou8jJQBZIixt0ue8u6iqZjEohHVLzUtuoMdRfTDI0OtjyMVmonw7xitKHjAtDAvIHsFEBKAcD6g1C/pEIBMDSESVXFqJ/@8Z91ej3A02i3QTIJdn3LOmabxl2FCguDGUOGBXGoU7EALoW58@SQwY2iax3FxeyNsciCCkG53ppDvcNMyNC@1aCX9pUb6NnQudquypmcD9UpNlCuuTTROOdCxQdKCxqWMqC8qdpp9nwDWqmtRqLEM@nB0O2WWdraYjEn@0P82Wr82ZMLFQqXyCSWFrPZXhUYLrNEQeCLPcY5bxsTA4zjKo6pdSLW2O2bRp6l20xq10xLNeKxCRyxVMxuxRIZlHLxRFWrtTNdzejEY2vAi3XIOJaotmvtc231sjqVPJwloLlFNNhd1Xg7IUVA5FCnuMkOQBZnQLS/TQtXKM50mkhyjM6EgpEw02E3PCBKqgrypYkMAnIo4@iqasVzGTmBYgLh5tYbI@bVdAqHqPCqdpmMRWPJcNUJA9R0oqLYWU80E8WWbvVxyAGiGI4FI4GNvNuGcRYlo6O5oC@mWIv4mkYRkCwkE2/VmK3igOzzEXVJ3uUwfRoFpcAQdKHJnqx2Qh0ZhAD0ZdeZkca6eQsZUplwmAHRYWCmSg@aBhLzijR4RXhOFDJZJa4mALaWysrplgadALsbyHTB86G6AXghz2EAG@8kIdkzUMaApc2H1aDDMK0LfWkA4gF0mbaKMgeEj8oHFMxkSP3PAQ0ZdeVcOl8sTvaxmS7m2tlG@nsQ0p@yj/YkrHxjQmmAkaer3jJdMXpDpadyPYop7bZquUJQQU0cF0TR9HhDgWkxeGacfmTx@XTeNIh4qkWQBwp53npiKFRQugg1Pa2DMGWKmGiA3meDWNLH07kDwM1U5tIHBJkowAfpgSJ4GgAwmTpS20MXpBow8G1fa/eBZ7F0BpeLfBCazh6CwrmDZE93/ayxMHL9aT6SyfpBWIwHUaSxRWfxwOCKqOoTAdT44YDHMSvOYA5i0y8iDASh0ExWyQDvfQHnwDTMOUiBkD5aBJmM4e0AmtgxKpQwcHlqF3VWX8v0mwjaDNX4DvJf33UtZxXGCc3tD1sZ4JTsiT3edQ8MZJasa4811@Tulm62QCw70D@zXg7Z9rCljaYqRGF@G145kRtQwLoOq8HI/XEIXBePdR0QmBS@gcChKIkEN6HgvxIAElAGCBXvOiSKt0GoHI@NdlzKUFfKQKeTUkzCjivBZEXCVD5dNswBSiF2RooBanowadMM1PSFzCeRr8wd6nzZT3pdLJa5MjUjfhd78uRJbDVWB8n@5MkzcK2h6xm6kuB6Rq40uRAugy5KkSIXxp5TCgy7jN2fe5hHiUtsthGOSp80K66cr64WLlPKuSyeeXwmQNSBZAPoND4ATyxRq6EzkZDqt1DRTKs7WfsNlM7HbVuzBBFeKjcK9wsqFIgM2sDCSaCtVnGQfZwmg5oNoyAore1@3I5dnOcuLi/uLjrJi/tYClMnqkqtBZWC/OKDTM82hzBcJs6XV9PyZSJxXoBBslWL5WJL8Xg5rUNGSiLxXTmRVDi14zEVpHb84iIGRBX0OW/3bcI3SuUTCZ9UUA4cmEEnjMcyd2XIv5W4TCRjkDYRS8EUoxaLAWXaSASHKo2cOUGgg6NXnDAbyWSE2NC0r/E7I/YhLAMTLJ58G/h343hy0jq4BunK2o6Oqkja5toIeLNLPLBDD1/jWmW7pLEaMNxCDWC07fgzI5xLG0PSn0m5NcMZ0XQQISgMxx6Uq9oEDCLuaiOYIEC/H3uKEI7fqAttwITT1NXMGakmEoOOw7C7Z@ZqQ4d8WMm0nYAHQO8Bp6UrbejYk@guJHYBCIHPs9n5MYnqDOJpVYlmNV@qIwwsbcVA@nU00tqHmtNH8oJmhVMJuwtURZUddAOVqLbL2jDm94DS6khzuQ4PfHSMSXYUJ55ArbHBtS5U9lBjwEJ5NgAazs02zHdU0Bwwlk8e2ZZxo9mmgUTObAFqYPgqtsEU8nnkBTZqNHbzmw/Tdx5yoNhMsByibRjrNHHbTptlDVM3eyZbAgBkzUyGM/au0YYigM7nwvSSOdonIlCjZxrjKR5Ucbh3UEeUSwVf@1YQMkvwmSuQNWx@pQOAB@p8vPv9FowQcjGXg/J7vhx9/EqGsEzXEQPbLAAQBlcd@QZb8nvV6o8nzEHIH3wWCfxkqrxj8nm9AgMqlEr08E@UNNzJeQj0cy@q47nm1X2LNCQ0ZYRnGRO1B2UQ@qmoDu82UMPoVDCGeqSYQDrT4EH7boPsPOkP1Yja7ptMugANI19n2Y56k0WBI4Gg64OqnIasVJuUMT@ZMABHXHMIWl1H1bWB5u6SuUs3UHUJhmUvFm1uAYJDTXUjYr4RiFc0SQWy1uhx@K0RDkhORKUn2z/Y3GoeNk52alJ26NhZXWsBB3fU5gAUT111JDb9ibIjFZCJ9J@u9SPTdGu8ua519sVPFNN4yfc2m3u760eNo/e8EITG0QZDXcGirC5OAWDyY4r2elXIDti1zYGvkTuiIRYLSHp1wmKP01MRu4yxQ2GvD4WXMHyANvhMO9Jrt1na5F4/UACuICDa5WkM6yWTCEl2ej9QQJYJJdrqM3bLC6xgoG@ln7BfB@jmxT@cSGC@k3P3iNwxho4VqtmdLFP4jdvt4qjtB@cp@DqNrK4HwQUK5lb@Sfu6IMtM1FxgH98y4eOrA3PxzUTNBfbxFTk@XFWYj24qZh6oj6xEyHAVYi6uqYg5gD6mFcIUXrkI4soU99CyhchrbvSDiXzcFcKNSxsBKlroEEEeYJ5zx4AvOzhNtJEGPJKXJ2Ixii9WsHQHJidrCIL88hmXMSAItDjH6mTckRugKIRRpEHn4IsYfjxnBFlvKk3olUFpvZBQFEvrIMDkUpC46Cc2p5KaWhDsg/N2zetNEAHDUJf2QsJRfiLehN5qSbhT5HkL2qY1DvXluzwn/kAT4iTUuwqc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vxYSUaS7gTmBI3TNBEdrTHFqTDEu8iK@wX0Qkb9YxoV5LQUw@sP6x9M18s6UURkSyGMTltYmT3cDVzGXkImLxUQyu9dmUXdAZ6WcCdKZQszF8DBi0uvQzB2BVWMRguMMlHqTKS7Tqo9HOBA1evSUwmtsTMqCWZijZI3rgLH9eeSbtFROFaandISi3WZh8ofsLYOlKmSC7rZb2ECjQBYvuPeeA2cPWPLJBL@zPmLTYBOHdoe3qakc8/8MvOtAAs83TV8ak0PuOJtCNeKP7YGuJpOihn/ktSzBXQ11TiAzk@hLKtoKrCIruO@ajRs2EpdN9xR6g3iwaF5gTf6DXPMJnvOS2qg87qvecnwmReNJwxlMb2oBqBE@c@NE094HkU2Y/np6mTrqpdAgLn@BoatDavF3UEVf1Qxo0yJivKKdnnWPBcpjbH7pD/osrYF9qV83C73yqrE4yWa6otGQ1azpKS1Mf4QNbuR52zLR13aNKY9FKD3E770RoTEp3deWaO5vonE8AXkVb6/VU23s@BHbbB52dJhvZW3o8wiqexsRIB1Yew2nr/PchEG8Hie94mE6aTj/fwpDEIm3oNUhaXOZOh8ikTRFWV1pjnHT1v52zMENSRUHw1NrJZK6AY6e/phEsqFvWw@lxwKX0lcr81HyBnZNk3lQkyxfW09zgRHUWS@1f6PUwcmkDRU/nOyHng0LcM2YGrjmgNANPt3XFAWZyRXOoN9B89PMYg@Ng1Ea2ClyPsHdQHG9p66FVkiCNBRqGrjkW73HC85A0nbYvB2hwpwP9BEnRN0vfDim5Tj/tu@YLBLPt4krFA/z2FQKOLxLgMkyIgTLmQ7Rrm7f4fVDF6Js3Kv@dP@h9mluqrxBVaZ04Q2vPSd5pf4ldca2bfuZT8Xpuqdy2PjdcWOQn1fyvZWhH000H5tv4@xghQHN2HP47n5XDNNMUI02G47B7fjJRKItlhKHsgZZU9J6pl8q9rAI/Dzb30O6i@BfPrxV7vtiS5S@LLU87Mg1ZPB@U99dZ@/pLnEDWZRtXoULORwbbebJLrF48XEGYQ@DS8vzKbefKlDKT5caPhxrAbvdvlbH3/BlDykPU9YYUa0y6NSh/mKBSBodrc3375@S2/Hhuna8TSDNoV75UiVDjXusqiGf6nWlSls/J35hCzuW@Xjx19aE6VOdqeQetKxW3BnIzLe5IUHSdL2@e7B58Y6FyohqLwkyYBeKhkdCH@iRmjl9Vahy80feogFF0DTr5F1WcufLOAoXcwsn2ITgO0TGbsGcMrYnGDdHuaGgcPU65vuX1bLMzUUiM@VaJVP6yIjWhszsqfR/S77cGJsyPzQEoDMZXtL9AShYN/juBmEICNWPC8DE3e3@pGhRaUDygRbVrJ402768TOvmHJvUEXKnAtM1Q3TH@PkTpeUK0ZZr6t7QMyNKORluA9TRuG/1SC80oOWLXAgvMFw6aQlrdhwwXfJwRM0ygHs6m3Ufmz2Ez0yNTwhmT@SOjVciA/qVJJozUZBly7Lbnfoghj7BTy5lyZuVRduQ6qNlSdYU/RqXlx/BVMoVH8flah1BuacEFF2n4skywrhWdEj3WGIildWCC0lcHKnkf0eyVztXQ8R4PAo1M/M6JzmRpkeGBdJYGfd3A34kloJA25JoGTKlcxe6pOCfRcW1ShD4kX721i7nE3R0oPZWfEHhMdASmCdzOxmdygXO@kWKV7zBpQzK@AP84K0DHuVbHjveci/D1uA3tORw8im1eH2@jBfSLnTqTnbtk8wV1z@ibfaOv9m3qHL7voe4BHOnysx2PVQLK31eca9y/R/IomMv1nTB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@cbZLdx734Gk34R3rLQgQjy@aMeDIZuIRGP3Q32nrw5hZHJM17TUNPkeAtXR4sN/59ubdw9iDjvTVLvDNx@g@U9xtZauslsNinDlhFe851uTWrqp4BbRR5R3oIz3/Br7VNu0v2j86Cmma1n0aFr60KEfsvOmu/MNmKtsm0r6NcyguXzfB2dZtWe22n3tS0VqqYpraNdZz5DDvY/OS4UwppprLL2JwRldA1rZ4wwyQS0cf4yP3YfGv9DyzNzabwxte/xlwTC5mu/bW/kqAToeyl8svM6JpiEfNzZ5G3geWaoQ67QPchMp0Kgsp9UcaCXyg/afiT1cQnrRguEDSs9UvakwoTWyb7FfioV@suRpoc0KED7PePGQINwR8g1mhfGdYc9JfJlx@x3QqfBnLsJGDw878dUkRzdvQ9Zm6PqKIR5zR2V/RfGxhZHioysj88icyYq1zbQ6fNDepWuWw39ZupufW7zZxfpZqPH82a9oso7a5b9f0vQGpo0b20GlSLdt1WmjGRylMZeSXAQZZg@kclpnAbAHO7f4s3sD5ukqkyNe@t2@2lNwo9uehnvedGd2EATM09sEvgbxm6HiaG@GpqvOxTm9XeBrUL5Welp7Z6IFPIQedcWuKP6Y6BQYNNsQt33Nof3FnmN@R@IsRivvs5HTlnb/nNvjhpGQniS2ebL0LvO2g/oOtPVjvDI3r0ktVCy6Pyj4NJcMqOI5t57zt1Y8ZlW4HQ6soSMe83Mf4GmBsB15cE3hzq0GUjH9EYQw6yu6O9/WHDKmgn4lRsbA@ZDW/b2mmz32fTnHQB0DgYdKOEbxzQNHdCrNP7/gpMS2OwjTbHF4ysl4JxSjtEWRTjN4u9tZFM9YDFFKu6adYQQXjyvJZCIR4YnQzt0zAMyDojNieH6EHz9zmK45LsFqXXZ@zhbvRqu5Vfme1Zi0KrHLS44VP3SaYWtk0QGvI578fFG5rC3G0unYYuzCWGW5mA@u6tC@c8GVCdiuRg9e3oAEzFD4RlR0ezWu8vMxTp/OnoFu0wEd6dQg0wXqW/yUBz9CdIIL7P/@LzviSB5MpBxQLkC@AkHwRKo5UPvm7TOer8i9YVkKHulDHNAddX7AJL3RYMAnoEzxk3jmLTvdPimL8z3i@Ct4Dvlg65eCNy5O53F3rssbj5fG32kpMvZTeZVqm/pwYID62nH7ToYda7TxdmgHO@jAhWCGa6MO30mxXdZRcRmT9lPTtFU3zWs6GIEl@fd/yU810a5qsdvVy55OM4ZyxM3TMh0larfNIZTaQ/JJtU0BEkciQ@ccokEIhnCVhydwrzEdtwKOTHuHjSgbfuJoo3HM0lsshid78QxDVevGFxtHL96e5y5rP7JBVv0Pv8gm7gThpO/SlZIjpZgHUr1HxgpHFyE6iI0xaXEk8Qz9Leea2HJ@y9sDSKRwJsNd5x6PmaYleg0dGKXzkT43imsH4uimdvZOHQ3orCkxrHpLp45oq6eBQgsPcRoOdDDwJgg173W1xfiQ2y3Sxy4rQoZ4cksBFz@dSpuw8QQNJlkcsc@sj0yWbuPGYPBxQup4aGtQW/f2tRTCu4@ym2prSEvuN/lMvlCj6iw2a2t1ctlqx8TDk@c/XIzyufTFaGXrMut4RL24GH2Xy78DqpswpVp8msWet7W/ebeYqec@f3aUMZOk@1iV75ACMbF4d7h7uHV80jg5PYZWuPfEz7ZpD5RA1iAX0VbfvqnTsVSgi62pzjfIH98H4PE4W1TYGl6XkEhEwrtYCVTQWkpLi9wZEk0Tqb@QfF56Rw3FzwIImdbVmMdRu6DsYhsCsyHVsPJDCw/XMpFWHBAkLtNQxmMH8gmD@9DmyFIilcRqQKw0EOsrScUeruwzHvY1FPsilsfJ9mwuCFLMz@/cj@dVnEuC@99JvS0YKH/7enMsj9ebYB6pN4D6oV6a7cbu3unR1mQy4DF6ktStVYpi@zYXztjTuMnDOxFJJ11EQrT51CQmUQLuFYMZ3YXRUt1bFaolhGN7wBMTh1L5pUjAmECZGl4oclnltIjHqQSog1SxWlO7y7vaKFREb4wOobvjVfSFwLbko/YKnpEE5ihdD5HBj1cNxCrI5XW9QxLiQl7HnLD6k/J6HFYNx2hQHynVA0OVP@o4DP5Do5Lnyl@yERPDmXzJ0iwPX12FqVPfh01U@RjFFjkhpEVedskvL15NAGXqXCk01aIdUWIDPYzSumLhOWgBvQ/Tm1X2cWjSaR1PmPj6xS0q8gq/hYOatq1gbegUkOHimWZv3CJ8u9vHNdTOuGpG8j3Mc0MDByoACt2JsTUCHR2YrUuynp@u5yQ3xUFub6gkW5wjDm76WoLDbjSHbHXYCF3UcXSQlFgbUXG8TobOabGG7oBO0oHhm1@@QspJhnbq8u26aYNJUeDJjK8yppgUQVinNnuwF4bS2zYMqx944kWCI8xOCGds7Uk6DZTraQZzDA1mUO4qmhTJCLDKXHuIC9/12EwSrwir5Er33YEeApxzxcGFmv3pH/8Zv9bgwgX3Hwr3KLcOvj8Svi64/5EXI8vg@ye@Lw@@P@a@H7LYZLNnuWfKif1cVIyXz29BbL23u4fMIVsmts9AGYVIj1ID@UgzgAbaABr6htoNwXkOQbMEeOLnb6HZgVegzVFlQS2F8lPtyzie0l3NZlGjxwlWhna/qiNuyKRDux@HeFkFKFbZUrG0LGehkOkbDyGdnOvhdkuOMJFYBTkXudGs2odWGzfHM8lpK7paK1V5e2cXlR8K0ge/oIsAG@HK/zmDNLif3k8BcXWRLL6oJOUEJsXBKSbHUE51TM4@oOHFyQEgCQw2vKNHoEKaglTAm4Y6ckkLGnuTmhZeKYQGF5VfWeIhSgMijhuvVJjuYsEGStxvHup0mXAzSGcIdoxgq9I8Bjz/gV24F8aluFqDATP9ag47GuD@h3Pu2@CchWcJZy96iE9f04C1Yc@PDRM32m5DaVk8n80XsnIpEeJQSaCC8mL3/QwoocOCAGir2pVpOY2Nrd2XB4fHMxcWEGRsGizGYvW15EU6kzq/9B0xv9yTRF3fzh6/Xt/2SBkuVbAMjRDBWvR0MeflNl3SB3I/4ztXZ/OmiJmM5NzXIqaFn/Q2bdWYxR7EZkOAG3zH3Eyu8cTd/fnlWv3CiM5k/3neJS7RzBIyF7guHLrCJTZdTCzirrcf9wSvdnMy3lmMvBRcUeSfEuH@IPjhKwf8i@KCewe8nb8ROhHoHwiMZB7YEwx1z2R5VnTonhfMKy/IGq@oMhY1yLAdmdlKEC4NE3WZvdNOHHnxiXTA7ULejWQOh3RIOHPLEV3@4dPMhzvxMGLXD24CEEfg@1A6XWtFbsVpTe/AkH9SM@NYuubGExFDQEwfHZqFdB49UO@DKbXzEfPPyjioB44ydA1LnO6rub2M8PsImHdtQJJuHjgcAt0OTYsFlrFN1XMdgZ7ENoeQRRsnWS@HA4Dr0uNIxdFCBc0pDYmBnjGvKOd41l5QIjPoFOOjRKavjjpaD0aceCIFouk7WQ7uLFDw0D3oSq15NUBTk9VXoA7YNIU1PPI/SqxVyBtUkK@EsNv5wcZlBJBh0lZilVsjYqeGd70MNvwqi6V8yrQSqViG8dmRuDmGlkPJuJRhG33cPEbmjG5XIzUsfBKYD@ZdzR5ksFYwzHAWeoFbR8Nc803XR4Qoo5wrGc3oqKM4ntRdvUQ6QXjs9uwmlpBmWJzusBA3FnSmL7PwZKHiCqEUXAQxJe8qFV/OTYqGSiXTdyJ46gomGpDjsWvvgRNUhHh3oFgsPqTbQByWYeSNX8SNlOPaCZau43B9ywyWTJKdAh4UAfMQBO2SS6Nj13G8PCuerUEjYahjdPDxSbPYuZzJXIKbMkmwRbRRboA2hda9RATmnZBkldCCfgF/q1giflFhRlxYuEjZRuhAPkDNjSY51euTfAFaUK1Z/Wlw@jkkYDhVK5VV0RqT0r7CgC/W5ghEQDtHint6P9BXnJsBqqGMBqgNW@1oIC@fv1INQwUCAc8M8F5GZQhMZidS3pWhqeBSMMohyou4Iw7iQEEnLwvbit3pJqhri9kqmbuq96DWfLhAvaYrNJtx9r/OZrLVu/iiXhtnQddM1OOL/ZqcLCwlk4vGUnzRQG3r6VO0kt0vgjLXzMCkcwRA6UU9UQV@BuWvtmhUF5W1@GKnll@iFOCFae8dJPjRyWbuFpX77OJTUJZSEGJzoRNfdOgej1wmI99D@bCHLGZTwDN3eCEFXQSK2S9qySSWIbPYxAL8mL04TtKweXGcJYNcVej32d5AdLcpVcxviZkLTDkBRfCqP2AVccAS@6maHnBwVVhhXtwD6h/P@BXuOmW0WK464QmVNBnz9YJFyGmUuULIxPlFKkDAURyIiN6UkkiAMPnNb6JyiTHpWakQN5PPirlqMlaUYeoNc@boc9DDs0uSLd1dbKZvmJqOnXeVYubj5eH14eG7xEWcVVgsunEgycvSD6ySZ1/3WWH5Bz7st/lEo0vZSDS7JD9dyWY/fPgAMw74nNczdRAf/JM4T8cuz@MrjNVXVpZSpfJS6nmsGSpYIp7PJ45Zll1ommY5nQ58zT7d2huP8s@zZ5QXTOnhn/Ewkb9weB4EEaHRb4VTilF2saIoS8nl/HOjCkWr4KfAZHDibxm@MisW2RZ@/uZ//5s//Zs/ob8/pe@/U9g1@wSf6y7Df3J/6oTcCrpb3U94zwlMLWokF6xYrFiIHf8QY//JPk@YXH@28h//5OBj1I3W89kzG55u9GO0VI5yJzjAV/B8N9F6dA3BSvfRcbZWq4Fz5T/@r5C@/hLwYMx4DX7qRQ9XaRytp2uU5HO0XgKHnM9Dvv/3L34RidZH0U9RWZajY/prRnMyfspP5aeMgSMrrZQl03zulbdcGvkfLywry/mLoD1DzY1N6wf3IR9oV2ZGJ0HJ7XMVE9xAjm@BwytrS0@ef9hkTIWhFj@rq89nCL435T/KpOGTEd1ghJ70yKtCtFxLNXn2Pq9GQ46pCvu/TNTd938jXCTqXc@YPle6l2wU@lxE5fLywfPRV39YUGiPiNGAdn7mbDrMo7rvYV6nZ98CF4n@WKsdufj3uoV/h8f493PFHHsGnyfwR//w8b34@4RCRDCBzH6e/BbdNRI9j55fXr7p05@NfzsG/rU@4t/eJ/x74@LfSRv/jt7g30OViUTX1taiyeQRqIaCZ7/mcwrfTKYpfB7vIrrf6YctH5QOnkdYNH2ZTN/fn2d@GCWrVfEPSlPV9@GHu6BYl/fp9NoP9WTynIp3XhflXEtf1qGsvMj088MaIE6una@tZZr1ej19@UP9fG0ykUj3/HkS@@lzSFi/PD@PRO@wLWr4s4Q/bQd/85KUJS8OFjA6V8DFyEkPEcDoXnX0R6If1j7Ek8@Sz3J67iYnX8vXr82D4P/gYAQR2ih3Zdq5fq4vd0Aispx6mhvnxqPcwDyQO@BU4S83AKeW645yvZyRM2R5PJpA9fD/4MB0Xx@YgM2ElO4o5yLiXBeevYOD14CvC3lfwZ@Wy@VGUMhR7gb@czoKarr0iZ4/NBMXkXMmfVBh9M/IsUwulinFYtplsWR9vLi7z5c@SqlY8@I8dlmNZp2LiyzXjlh@uUpXft3fN5tb@5vNZhb5aG0x@TyZfg6fWj25Jh7PovXqs4vVNLYf579MM5pde3ZRL6TRXUpCI@UhbC2b/MZPgBKe9ScXEZjwnZ3h9@z25pa7yEGui7MzPxZ/shhELgqCD4Bm56afcDDQNH9P/52D/7z@X5@y@PllgrH43f1anD4J/Esk7u7v7sVvPRGPC098Df4wAPyY5O6@jk4CugPXeTxxmbi/52HwG0@scYR1zGOtTokDQOiwUZ7rRawKGl5tMS4Wyi4uRrlcotqCEN@8rnymNZdElXajLLZwnQxmA/JSgkCKy9XqsnCvlKvVsnDLpVK1uuRD5cAjnACkOkq7ioxejSawCHxuEJezebSqVGDCJRfW1krFer1UBE@pnEjHcxhFdy7GLmKWZV3EMmRez9Cxs1qtYdvKmKwyyzDfu4DuFcMdKrVKEe@Xrcimna4UErFE4gdZoM4neBmk88VYlO9QYXJ5hQLvL1UnGqWwaFR1YotZKQpc6rC7@yhRiy0XE/HWWE2w5VK8nKyIv9qTBFvL1peY@Ds/LySXl1aWnl9eBmoAdurqnVKT72t3yipO6e@rbXEHIe5AU54@LVQ@f5bLuepFpNncbJw0mniZuyShxLQYw1CSDxFc37Ps2DkZYIqVy3Ms/OVFLLZafc7boVxk0VhVwKVjIGlYuUJ1jMIsT@vi3tMRCmLxXZWX8oUn2eLou9JWDrTiz0v4OT8/L@fLySWQREuVyuXlJYV@fkJpzgej7iVdh1NLn8ul4mUa1Y2rUXcJCiuvFKJLEYt286zkWAcXRG00aD2BwL7isBauXTuqrnv3Pt6att651ToqYD/ca2xsnaTya4Ayv93YSOWPT9ejMnqLgZ@iC@g/2mpsHpxCgsO9rcbx1ovdt1unhxDuwKAGxILP4FBRh2pTvR0Ob9HfVOmzoTnK1ZViWU3gLWvU/elXf/DTr/67n/78j3/68z/46c//9Ne//NM/gO9fwveP@fOP/02liL@//uU/@Z9/@ld/DoH/Dr7/Fr7/x69/@c9/wb/k/2v4/p@hsL8W3xAc/wIpAdsf/fqXf/IXv/7lP/oX8P2X4vsvpr8//bP/jf//X@IPnX/@0z/7a/wRnj/4Y0D4d3/1K/z/k7/6u3/7K/z/X/713/3V//B3f/Q/kePPuOP/@Zf/hv/@7d//g7/9b/7p3/79Xz7w@weP/v7yK8J/@XsI@fpyfg2er6nXt4b88meV57ehRpALMdWf/sOf/vk/AG79Z9z334MP/v2oP/Q9fkySpl/pZBD4h4x9zoKCk3v@2QcFlP8jhkIw@zyJjUJzXuivf/lP/wKDJ2D/QRhDTp6FXURgP7c/BNh/5RcsDPuHP/3qFz/9xX/706/@7Kdf/REKsfRyJdVIpeUvzGAAsPgVcAhY@ho4AITBZW2NPWFPInlwPFlDw0JETn74ACR9Ai5QlJcixQL4InKd3DK6ISHMO5b4zDeJ83n4jiLLFfCBA4JG5ICoJEStJ1mtVktGRjWII1DwYpoRq5dxjoq6fQ3wYiKeJtUsg97IRuuEBVLWkkesuVQb8YRJDKgTBoYFwqAjSc5LyXJtEzKsjTYZ4kLkycgHeH6o1cu1UR3R/UhFABzJdcgSoGpYulH9R/DXCCfAR0abP0JRyrVksl6GkBpVlXJLNSlPuUiVo7onGdUbwxlDS9ez54x9J8llic@xgJRMQONvMoB@RpaGZxB/kVwS1aF/z0nfJUwP7TQi@vAwHv8Mgym9AAC86TTuWYJvOo2leQ7RI44qSdnCI8kxAOWSwiTjB9DImowkqX2T5IH8oQxf91mrhzyIDquzuLgIrrW6VJAOQFln9vWq4yo2mv9Ja1llUqkiYTBuF1EXD0mdX9pcgl8Z/ree0DZOTo6lyGIMh@8Y8/JIJwvmshml0ntVo7osUcmTBBeJBuFchaQ1HND9llkiEqfLixM0J1Qt0Foir53eujli8VxKklJyqcJNoWLK@N5cXa39KC@vROBJ/iHemyxu8IVmwHfpZLB3IUHrd@k16mngBBWjFKnXxToUkyP1460TSHBywOR8LsNADbxbXskvF5eL@UKpVFzJy8ulynKpWC6AhCrlivm8XFlerpQrK/dQoOfQz1OrS63iWv3vzXz@q7837zM/FD@R@js2yrDDwzfp@0h9lE5n81TkmlxcqY5rUBAKitRJe@I66Pgu7TgMmydyQduY7nB3DRQtcpdGVl2AD4ssRNgCBMEHMKMVnoml4d2Dqlgjw1vp@TqZJBeBGRKRC2AGji1ihT8RbLinIG2eytxZLAXOHDojJ3giYx8ygHYw2B5uMHRNdmLyjWzravsBiI0@fwPThm2CvvnzYdYV45pHbWp421vb9aN2FLzOxRlobv8BiFNrgMfXVPv3hmFr0IICoqGQA6zDj62b5jyAFXZ6@EAtX/snt3DJjY5uAfjR7oudk9DzZKuxsRMpsfWD/c2pR1EAFdne1vaJ713hsV7Soo/i/dbe3rRXPHDO8IQVV1IpEHzwg88UfeiZWfzBA5EzD4@IaiaXklPNsXqXTt@3VLyr@5jfRu7iCnqXGF83HTkW66kDGMigq8rAzbiZtWfqMEtazG3kcHEg@xlnOU01XxyzRZB7bb0CM0a2VqyXolJRKtfy5VIO5oC1JF2Z3jXiLFGNlnBKeF65rI1YgZXPL62oE3mN27UqMj9KoDmRHZibDPC6aDyO7EZstQPzlFuDTkm08NUsQ4s9GAgPDEKnrfX6IABvTR/AAX5uKQqD77d@AIca/riPB7g8DwqbidFnwSO3vlXHN9cw327DpcIZbuOlIzze2jCNMc5q5ASlMb2wh@GZqhbecU9nQ2GY54c96UZ6FWRzJRLB9TCty3KRDFm58pVysVwp5MupcqW8XIQZYzEl51PySnmlAsySk8tyqVysyKnycqWwDJIZYouVlUgUpJfWzWZh4JEliZ6a0ca7J9fwEk8z069HotDw2JfYCF9xFlX8gGGZSYXyRY5BQimC21mXRjUJXwGYwxfsyVJEUlibRbe3N3Lb25K0jh406W3kJKmDnmI5l1tZlySVYjZg9MhDoj76tkqowEqShp6NxvY2YrhCT76MOCTpmsdwj@55VgDMQE@hQBqwJH300eUAuclLVKZULvfkcusbkjTkxcNzdwDX4L5lKuwWejACE23zmA2Ik6QXXqIckEE64nAiqx2vvo2GJO1yT6OBKF5S5Yu8Uq/Q06APJLLBB4wvST1w9GyYyUtSC5zI/pLUBld7rEDYAFx4ms5wFUka83pgTSRpRNBK@1oCxU6EQz5Qnp0dpe921B7/jG3@bEPULkRpo@HWduvFi1av17LHja0XRxT18uWOcjUe2q1eSyRsNeFjYiqIuh6Mpz8qRjWbij4/6hVEGVNRzXFTpRI2lY9QMvHpYUaD5kuMeglR8xaABEL4DAC4hZ/1ATzXlRaP8j4URc9RqyVVkWWx63TjxLhKih4tlrhDkRhXnoGmviytonA1u6BfDcuJdPHZsCyVVqTVJXhKz6QCOEfxXCzHmBS7kKQECMVn0kpRWo09e5aOPZWfMWmlIq1KKytSonqPcjmeuOvGR6lRLQcB2ewa9mPsefAElUXoGyfqyM3sqLj5op1On0181tbOAA4PjuN5uP3hgK2zWxIduDve20zcrK2DnMhVDTxZrKJ3cRQdReodxVVg5rF@N1xdFbD31V7tHBF8xp@1tHRWP5MuWTjf4koOSnVqtPMra2vnny9B7arJ1XEURpJ8uTrC58pyWOFa1BXHXZRX8qvnw8XztHz55Enuc29N@r5OmFHxor@wiQ5kVRXCPGpw6Rbtah8gnq2m@UsN5HIpkcHt2k2z26SLy9mHkBDDhFZNtJnE4vjWEb43JB6LreRjsUSsCsBPIFg0BjW211oSCEporUoeFLuqrbpDUCNy1XuvLH42XKksyZHofaSDd1cuVyLRu8j93f1a3RulX7HxWEmmPe9TxnpJmF9kaSkAFxGekCudqT9njVqjd9SoCtDGBs0CgCEu@DGidPbJty44JNfqP/DnRR0X4CCfCBWfL8pl15L1bL1ev4hIkhSVfHtxuQhzB5xg/xglGzDbuOsODTp@vPoaCaasck3j/DLx476m35UL6TrtdYkDO99Hk2tZXMnK1LNErfYBrfNGooYpnGiNdIG746A@FyWcqKjMOq78sPJD@YfXpwenB9vseW61vFrmpKCF9@eplByTY0Da5zBoaUdbkaj12SzKPxovq9FVK1ZYjhUmFKSLmjhFG0dOiJ@jff28cHl5DpOQywT4arX8M7lYTi6vyiuJaB1P8@VXonVyQK9JF6KX3FAdX15hCfCQ3TcvR@tZES6vyImok44KE/dKEVSgaPn1h88wgRRvRdTy5MpmRakW79fu4b9@fw5zrHuaat3TP/5k4eeeA8A/gvse/gg@IbgwTBB/@WN6jf@v0c/GAS@zVAKKRz/U6tCwPzR/aEYj0UqsnszG8P284iMmL6jOLBn0pzpL@PdDELAEGtiS7wPv2hIr1mFury5ls9mLxJs8qCOVSqlcikZ@M/vJLsE8a2mhwWL8Fg@uBtGLqr3jIrGJ1yvh9HhpIb15fLDxCmahoAepBr5mjm0c7GcwCt@EFpz3aeuqYutj8Sq0MUKh@nSycYivOj7dPKQ0Z3TSi0JpFixyWdztrIo3EaRumJwpsHwuV8zmlrNykcnl1dzKar7EFF2FCfbWyBKuRUzKqFobpjXmOmt8I0GJFxoIg3F7Gkw@HHWVvTjcoxR06HtpYXPr9QE72N97n/FCefjJzu4xOz7YPjlrHG1BPV5vHTOpccx2jyV2tnuyc3B6whr77xlEHzX2T3a3jhFBNoLyCtcgOMF8jY6tOWMn644t1SG1biLYMdvXqjsZrtiWksVL6SaDDbymXsXbnSfDhwbM4DphjfG4sQBzumEbXxDbvlY6HTuCR8y0NlvA0XZhSbVxz6bUzzkrrDh89ylnF5@w9vJ@bIW1c/tGYW2F6Tnxx/TlQeGIPXny5MKQqkIaR8LV8BXWcBBuZIawoEy7328txEvLbAnU1PxyIojZPzhcyHm@hbOjkwXZjzvaXMj7nt3thYLv2QLfsu/bPttcKPq@9carhVKQbH9jYcX3bW5tLJR9HzDpQiXAub@5IOciHrFuTK2zQK/YiW/v7m2xJQBKVCdi0S6BjqlgIER8aDj8vD@SnC0t3fZNfL83zF3GU9Ad9UvQHvgE1AIqFedI18sUWzIt@BmoAwCGZLS3OE6vUrJ77ZTAirfPwwgSuYssYIUWsEIAv4AnTRGOPamxfIJB9EKXr6PG@U0zKSadOnSe7DuHreH4XwdmSNF19nSuEFKo4o1YkYV7gTLeJdtNlzZWEqgMJZVsKZHAg0v7p3t7PDMLsjDtuESQjDzSHJymBdigivCLVYdQ3ji8WagtkFYLQoPAt3ZF7idaMzLdmkgKqOfCQhsQTFL3RtFTDPWpFC74IV708A3RAAzR4M6Bi5/YisfbWNee6rapQAkk5tbBNq8hLhnW2GQrJxhmSpSiaL7V@vNn5vku3EmvPek1Yhy3QM6LxfHxktYQNoFhC95ROYKgo76UcgE5JpmE1FAdigvVawGIDl9@MtgrZR0yysXY06dUjjXwVWKUBaZLUo4sjSCIQBCMyIfI/KI9oeImFrJLuADPX3mLRMRxhN8R1xr7txqAZJ0u6FSr@r3Qb84FQ3Xc6pRAFlHdDrY1uAv5JvhRPAInp1gLukmKeZFyCSNxWpBiaop1IXhKpjY1AzhXtQOZ6LECdEZq/f1N3kL8Cg8K5wFUY5B7q9RgICyeYvclRl9YaNmqcl31oEAeEhTwLTJNHAnB4R5Pd7RJyZZ4f0G2xNRfk3J3e9XjI54a2EFwGpEVT11zXhHVpcB6ADSDXyDD/lsD9JwlObJkUkD4XCbAtibh0mkOd@/x5RcqsTVdiyffXAsUyw/WYusrq/Hb1QKGtYBFoBYg4uOANwnQ9DPZmvl5KGAsJBRUm5@HAgbQgJegj08g@Ir0MOQG6dPfnh4G6dXprgz9FlqQSwWeZNLbnvR2Jr3YfSFEYTAlyC@zz6yFLrkELjypy8rg6HBZOZmwO@klq0GNqV6ari@BeQ7AcygqORgy4KwwRgmScfA@a2WA71SoscZ2c3d/62QyFvFlnKYoeB9fF0x5JCbBRIEw3omjJ@GXKN5FInB9M37I80gRPZvHJ0dbjdcpKF@CrQU9YFoHgB/REyZqcO/lAKGG2obxuJNi8eMGW0qwp1iyFBOWAfR8dRa66aiA6sEcO0MrT1nlOIjvn@xJUeyRkTlZSXEWT7DPFxcwpOZWmDywPhcGBWOl0GHjwgoquxyPr4MIKe8JmH3eNbmygZDAngreHzE3s6tcji3bBeaqfdC4Rzl7Fj/V6x7HNhoWvfOElkmTMqdKb5xG2SJuVIBxcVK1eVyLpLER@QBDsRtDGA7nZJpKkn6O7EmxnoLFy9JRv7UsX9JoJ8uS5mVZo0xny/AbYZ2D6VJk6swoXUxhWq6l4LFKEXlgod3kEIPsSITbU0L3E8VNvMneTazSvRIoU5owkmtusxl3VL2Lr60d2m0Y8lFddgQYfjA2wyOpI6FjMlKQB/WnyQj@Fni8TA5GnSmE9PbcGt2GFqccIxG/ZI6rWlSqUDHQJoavbwxniG8gD/uhWfF4UqjEiVWhFW8r2B88ZOcTV8pwHEOnn5oTDOJ5NtRn0zlxPtvMicObw@Yl8Y7Nzom7Gg7mlQAEwwMx4uDbnBjDPJiXgN/IEkRcnocIeB4m8OVlPDG/6aFfTbZ46Eodov@JPVTF/TC7ByEWBOVScGCoraObKjBtW8P7gacR@UdvIWV8lAidAvbZKhFwkuK0NW0avYdJIKJjbHQFLhut4gvAR9/J@XIiFUIYwohXvg0U/SGcLIQUSjgHSZS/qZl5lk7HR40sOI03SJ/BQ@xGB6Z3QQLTegQeYwNYbHwPeAHvFPJjfGae0@UCdKuzjEPhaG7H5pcnbl96CNqrhJwIE/S3zT79rdmnQ/ljn/xZWdfY@WQ5LpMhP76FPqij18F/VkZeqSdzS3xTjcNco6rXD7Av3qgRyoafpJ/M1kcjJJDPU15VCD0GfKWQQFxhRN8gX6j5xDnfeamD8WepxtKyn4ZLvKA3kFU9VPgI3gHQbOKFmM0m3YTWbKJlqdmUeA408OKAFx50RWfjcRnQUpsmxcaltCKlpHS6cbyxu5vWDCnFr1itSY5r2moTLzSSUh2YKNUkElhNhOmrulWTxJYoxWGUWno4j0YoD6jglzMhIJ4LvV07fNPll7Nrh6tkfkWVzKnMgtv3viK3I8oNDyU/lpPNr7HyMtoAv6vi1VW2qqGg4ZfHinek4vUFE6fm0aQvisDzdcjS5@BdBbxI9GhimGhrPPRPb6KtMbL2Sd4tHtLMpRuit6OpBxEEnMq5TzqkV04wutGpowo9i8xDGSm4oU8ULCNqGuJ3T0HjlyAEA9rkzR6ivCnPNumgGXOqqIFgMS2s/LmEF39AAxyaFvz6l3@A27/@A9x4AQgGeaIO3Hj7B6boCoe4CARcdBUIPIG9peA2wYEy0gZDNNyEj5cLTS4oFg75WBMa9SlyUvpxiiJERsdrWeMCbyIprUpQdYeuHZm@egTh590@kriMzApZuv8WixlSHeYhnXufSSL1O2ikkCKGotkRpYG0KYlJXAmhtPLqJUw@Q7zjiRhUn6fCTG71RERQk5SfPhivQreX1CamF0gRmDzwwgQJuJUp/GonUu4Tq74KErRYGIorbnPKjTsaHyx4GIOnqCUij8yk/n8zTwo3yX@mU6X/7ydFM1Of3/NU5pEpzDfPVn6H04L/otD/F4X@Zyj0vzNt/gGVfBrlbI@fUte/qIZ/u/pFMm8Mw4bdu0HTW/7n6GG/I0Vg5Zv0AK/U5/JjusCXx2cPTT48rP/MUTrym@xJp3S2bTYajZOBbB@9aPQa/cbRe/Cv5/aSZ1fL65u36y/WO43Nzd7L3sa@@qbcWN6zXr0rv3/R/fRRBe195@Dl9590q92PvDuybs/Uw9uCWnYaw@HH3Z2xu7N@Otg4Lr5fuc1t6cXuuvpxU3c2X5@8e3XyonicvP348vDlp0Fu4Bx2c0plUNh5XXq7MT4zIsUb7bSzvacdDI47W6f5wd6m9n47uZHbO668kXN7W7ffFzZuk8Vcdtd6dfDi6PSqtfW9frS7976z8dFUSh@vb63dbKfS3bg6ehs5KLyRdz4eHPS28pUXO9nbza7VyeV3dLt49e7ocP30/U7/lbI12C6eVt5djQ9L/Tdvbtz9ZG/5rDR87SwnjcabN/lXxoubm62jSEsxT@yCema@ka3b20OzMlhRX@3v9AZvbNnIHhTfJo8HJ7ebW@v6x5VR4fT92Zvb5eP3w9dvXn5/kNOOj1tbSslqdfLHVyfLkfagsJu8Od06LSsvOmdvBje7O8X3m9nXfXW/0TnUr1/0dr43jw/3dhsFZ2jIexs3@vsX/avX15sbu7p5eK0bjeVsUT/pvD84iJy@1Fqb6s4752Xjqv8@W1y/Xn6f7FgvTq4@9a9frh@fHpTzo8Nxztxwjlo73dHmUSlfzrb1j0efuuZr@fRNsnRz9TKvvW98ciOFT@NiZU9/rw6Ml8l27/vRRz2bPJXlje93P71/f7xzY7caxunHt9tHV/brjnHgHOSOXr563dKvy@6V9b1xfCy3cy/U69fJnBIZne440EbqiVJcORnsvbFGm@bHo93vndKn5M3ZdUHdvD562/h4lGvdGtY7w97TBhu5zoHSeGu6W8PRi3bl5vR6R9/7eOC8j7zekovFbbPrrHffLlfeZV8ku9cv3q3Lx6PcvnHUXS7Z@2/fnGnaVv/d6aejdnH7rVUeuEbvzafTwVZya2/U/6SWcy39@P21ETktHh8d5m@NV9rA3d45el1yD3J7bw87O2O58UaVb42VjXFxc2SXCmeb7@z31zuGlX2vfRwe5tSbZOe95S6/0Vrd9lutPXgVOX7ZP90/fHu7WyzZLwaGtn5Yzu3v7Wzs9zrLr8a7r4dbe62rzovdd@o766R0nd9aPyttvjsuuCfXr9xK@2ZQOCwnT/SB2ztNRl4O@8OVwzP749vR98uNQUstHOnvzfGKPNh4aeVHbxtbB59614eWuS9v58fZ0z3zWs99Orn9tOOUGuNkeXTqDkz3RB4V5TeRwu0ny31pvXxzfLD@8uD7l8qypp0pV8dvO7nCaTmr9e3Cbqn0Qt7a7g4@Diqq/GnzdUEpDPpJZ@8629nonL49u9avBq8GV@1IueK013e/HyrmVisv596vd7eK6t763omsnvZeHS9v7ucO33UOTz@OTjob74anbw@03NbVy8peb/nd0dvKq5XvT5wT5cx898rej4zKBdORS5XibeG4Uj7o28eFs6uK@/2rq9K6ftaSX@7mB@q2Zr8rj8vX1qf@be/2WM21ei82PypH3S2QpKeHOaU4vN4fHUcKb08GNyvWevL9dfvVO0PWy2faSvbk41Xlut9/dbvZXj5rfPqoFF9cqZXj7WxL3y6@SB5tvDm86m2efSovd3Lre2@Vd6Otvvs@8mZH27yqnF0fjMbym@3j8aCRM/TizfFZ8ebEXD8@2zku91@37G5r56oPsmEwPr26Hd7sqCv90W35Vf/qrZLbe1feMJzlw1zkpbo76BydvHrXSHbzasW9OXi/b52Vz0bF12XzrGIelLVXje6L0ZuD7lZuxdLOTkanW/3s@oY2KINMOdRP7Y2DNzvfn720cpG8UVr/tGEWVz4mb0bvS2fZw@Te8H37JD84s@2dd5q9/e7m8N2r48Zucrc1fnF4rRy83yoe729sOC@T21pJHe8Ubp3GRkHvmhFnsD7aH9lWpfD99V4PRgKzU@m8OCmcGU6j0b3dLR9vNRovnNbuS2U0etFdgTECP1tnb81a5Df8ZrEIv1SMPxR@qUFk4PRa5gjkJT@IFaHjMRE6HhPhB2JoOzTfafyb7FLkJHzQhV5MyA08wxYoa6xjovKQYbv@TZ14@X6KDUxIrqGrbVr0RLSurbWGLvocU4dfslfhUS96jZI6snRTw/ea4B3rOCe1VX6eDNSXTOTAYIMxzjdddcCP32j4ahJxsSZdy87fAEMX@0UW2m3mvWwqQ9dG@q@e@gAKhGX00nRPaI@l0@2urvQccOgdcn2IHPv3WGMOuqag8QOzkPeaipwriq2pqK5S4U7wjSr7L5hu8kvfvRmHAsrEmC50QCMVXeqg4rsrHe1G1cd0i7/ayUT4js@v2gUZDsNt3JNhdLnh1N5QUDdUe2oDqMUTeiut2aXneOHG86WsWGJFZaip2C3NxdcfNvnl/02eo7fnzZrce0gHK8UCLVeMULOha0G5c6CM0DeVCilG28nxIIErskfVEFVUb7fh0pJFKGnfFeOeEOYl62Hc2qD3u0I9gbujqRN4TaDVEGhFC9Iza/bfObTJ0QeqRvhi/da73ZOmeNUD32LIKfX4jssQlauez6ryGoTKL0o@uy0TdxhA8dHsyG/VharemJyXJdr3iNsjobVxhh3stqTX@2LREZtFu1HOly/5DsIcbd3zCO6neco54WmoVE8Dgi6IDRU@D3xlOr5Bk4PM1hcRd21VJQDazekdA5na7Pc75r0HWqalK8Y1uqp8qyzMF@x2qLHowvtQPdCU5ddF7J@kOQLWG5L622CDgkq23ywEIDbEes18amB3pv32mIa3sJ812scwD3/WpetmOx5EL3lbbnjdEl5OHH4qqwO0JHZxZ61pj3lGaJ6JV6sAgvt0SCaohrdbNVTrWkANREebekKlAL6tekF4ilsNyplij5eWZ/WE2IF2AM0vKt8MhFDnfrEueVYPy0KgdyJcmYmkAXG8LUTgzC4x17SACF3BcTCMEY/w3akzVOE7vXwuYpxO57lL@GfPwp5VvnEXO5SKZk8UIQnsxjhDnyqcX2gErftdB7MKWI8aCndwYxNqxItMgxk@hjMtmZxopxDycw3pJrMkUTs@JxbEkF8jQXpBe4KhPXHQGnwrLuvyHVyc1pEpEq1BRp8/@x0GvD43Hnrnc4El/JetIoNzzuR9WRC06vm9Tui7KSYgii9V72f30iN392ACbt5a2kjV4yAwm3gfl8UgSGxZsizuIAh/@xIEY2NT2YW8evIkDqnOCS5bvmRPWVxeW4uvpOMU9F05kfA7o0ieDyUPJQYhXa@zeH4pXvASL2NiQFmYRLA8H0GeI1heissegrxAIBcBA1cxCMl3rMy5dhJxOYTYx3s5CYMvzZiT@1I@KV@urZVxj2cocCpxfn7RlwrJPCTmqBeSkzEcLY8IhV9O1giQF/KhcSSEYjlZABQ86@RkRJDrVISfaTjP5cu5g9PvTHnxzml4gw8lx/fxqfZ5GeuLnMo3pVsM3JZri0B8J5JFb0YKwjhLLyGbg45AXRJy66t4aCrF34wlBi2gX3VqVAwdjiAIFANEBA@PlmJXj411rW8f7BC4SwY@XucUk1OsDNMQkCggMcqQGEQI0UDrNdsDy4eDobic4Du@@QBGmezjijOeH4B2QrXfy4nEGCcfrnADvjatlzdpDOH0jUOC5t7uOj7ebh3hjtnd/RfQhAtYjxQLfr1qPuEY/SpuKAZ/s4LmalAEkG18QiPqyptqMn8M9PIX2DzkAn4aO09ItUMIxhML7ZD4QnObmimwcVJ6fKS6REe6idAHKCeqMM9gtypTdCTHmL90tMzfB0SH3ig1kQocfkJRQKQQ0uzkqLF/vH1w9Jood9hs7B3uNBAzTDDbit1h9MYK7CCGoep8UPXpGcHhFyQ0r5PS8l6vQG@1JVj@OjNOPABsUkyTQqdLhPXlTD8Dz4PnJSCJ4kODUtHsqNYc3Lh31QcTlXHmIOStyEsthkJRpnkjIQ14syOhJ0frKOmIlqbqGDEXGJve4KEYXJ5kPXzrMMukV5pRz0U9qkf8YvP3PRXy9GJX5CNnaOHqsNqRwuRX2m3VoQsxAuoDSlXvUiZCsoQIBSHzax/ID342xR97BQ56rx0Nujlf7w3U3EllEbRHTrufpeOGFCSOxdOR7jy1ktQikTN/z@yE6qhNqowPZcZzu@K5XUFuXOCyq2mFTLs8v5pQxOaRR/PIc8V1Y08z4@qJv5WcWq4Lnd7p4w0uZAvhUocaDJsJ9wvZ5nhC1j31muyp14uDnjhfuXtcKROEndTIxIATjJ9iwtzpANniM7YNOrlCs6@hje3PPYZ6ix4aKflBJ2@KQfDEKU1Qpz04T3ziGaoHOQMxgTSk0zLnIrtLGlR8fHGBkKW98iRCugadwhRWAc0AaREcThN1JVXSdMREMRSIYlWMwnbH6@QEGQxmdmf6QBcCYSg/cBicSuDH@HhGZXTS@/NqhBo5JNBZKYLrquk0JEhwuwbpNCBusQ5UPM2dX43ybDVE5TydTOMnYFDUCbfMRQGCfoZ5D4R6mVfn1jtUD@8wHCZOhCqWq4oTFN6J3tNDVpALhdDx34OzfVYqBaeD8W4ptpzPBUeO8ZYpVqpEfpadLLAncH7EjiMaFNkKeQan7qALqroOnZg/OhoO/Vg2Pi0e8ce46itXS3wG6whxLIYGhw3wbdstFd8qjeu1LpNHciayAELxJPS@cm/wBsDeULEVw1X5GUsU5GJlFzOkhKjDqrbD32VOb/MGiU9vsXeGtsoNwBDSMdu0SRJxUDpo6eGAdiOlUGG4UW28BkBzxUH/BZI5gh24aKhzJvACPeFQ93iDk1CIBOrRaGThZKRhGanHTS/ClSd15WQvR6U82ZNpSPPe/IkFIPIKViEac3dkQRB4Zpih@fiSeFWS1yV94ED0zzMNzg4yfHLqzcMFGj7GzM78tcs5xhjirnZ4DBqJTUyEiup0mfDOwJEE8I5AtT07BAeix@iShifCxWejSEF8F7jGbeGMZARpETRK0ZBiI9fhLh1xZRhFL/jvPiZ@rkHvS4idAWNxYM4/HikgkOUTHEKcjZyGwP7JIUZhHFAK3lGXssH@gxHi8M@7ofgmDvFm4ehOiHkBIuDzWlK7ePn5mbT5tRB9lDLlR9KmS0pRiVBfng/GqyzAsHYhMCgUySOvUh7Y6WFw7s0DpNKTQeqxwk/k9rWFF9nNAE1Q4iuL7hPiXtjq5iGFxAPzRuWLVGJbjVAzQ@3DlSRoRMEIxLPU74WpQtDAkwq8dK1QCq4ze2k8SUIx4tDvrMgRUL5jKe8dB/YEum/mDM71zqso52Svql41qQXp/cO6ZtHQOFlX0S3CdU3Ls5VdCVXWO2U8UVmRyKvn7P0OBji6unnL71/AAUUSJ5el7zop9l0HF0NESHiM8qgxT/5NnnUOdcgfakGP9Ovnl5UOzfoe3lfF2iGK9jC/YzrEm/M6Ob6sloYAGcFNo@ptruepFhaEOgNKz0S6fEKYnX129lB0uyCvaas@3hK6l/cwBRxDWGrsR46HhqBPqj0B7IF9JjmPBUj4sPgS7jBsiIuEZJ7opB53YEQyKcaz2oQ1ODhA/SAjhrEI2Rk6ovxoepIps6UYYxwfJufj8JKI4T7o/9VwQcYPFgTJQWtEYqzz14z4lQj3v@3KaKC7WUJzA73LysPPR6GICf2tmPP0gLgV6Av@7IDPB8K6gVC0PWUQDVugwMPcmB@NTjHI/UH44IaRj3yBD4/mQUq6ASScjK6aCAskXsJ8aFpkhSYxs8Wk1iGKWrxNJstNDUmGEB87r8ZT6xyRZfNpXAbkzqQ8U6sJdIwOOZM1rsov/yBVFq94pnlq@PYPbPglrDwuWQbzLAsPB3u7HQiFNrB0lZ/ckfeajYNd/2orJt7urTomBjkZ0@5lb7VrLcsBI8fi2qq0OsR@jpdU8Zjm1ikMZXjhlJthxyrfrIB6L6plH2g6qQ4THzAR3oBlAHC3CxqvgS@Qb6nuLe4fEAicTLiwEK04oIebBhubZisovSJO5vACpKjsDhS@B4QZtuhV5G3FddSxmsWE2ZYOPwMF7/TNwpQ8izXMHhjqHqQ@hi6hZq6UGyWyGSoYnZyeypWum4uk0XZEMS6@3Jh2j6ANwaUXfLdMaBt/f6qYJNA1iKahj5mBVwD0FHzLNqP3rUJWyHm3UE3acSsWdWjLg0rziOVcpUTC3hEjHKXD8TuTgbhiIsJfzLmK5zscE9nFVmlvKiWf2NMytSeDd8zJTRR8nj8Z1sbLub68T8Pf4pHNhtKaxtfs@5i3x4Pu/wKyP7TzI5tF86ilK2Mm3Sp0mzLbWF7JlVZxrqX1DGJD7C14iU5IY1dHFr7eEjcG4DjupdXVG1VnBWzGt5ozBMBjdwhVikQtW@kNFA8wXlhlmE3oji6aX0@c6A@iTFOfDOniuQkWzKjxZBpjcoCNTnCJUQWJKYLFuKAmQGrBzzPc8myaFlsFR0dtDXs0GOC5LC8Fno5SUi1MoCTq8VbiGTxX4QlFp3tFoR9j56/591fhfiJTY@fQzS@Zt0AhVSNUC@j6NV76qpceRw4EC63owIDNVzVgRFhiTTEZ5VYCgMYxjN9tirJaGApUwwPpmLsHaLWhDPnmYi8Gq2iJSx0f3FOyxEJ7SkAk4H1TyJh0BVY261lGYg18UannWY/xWLIaxbk7MBHxUW/JJ4e3f6HLd5@s0Z1gjG7sJHImqt6uernK7j1A3AOCGg7uLEnHvJ0DqGHauDYT7EgB0kveLOwxtKECFL4ASQ2HbIbjUqgafIP3Jbd2CRVkOlq@9NawILyWq3rU4O819ts/WMx6yltzgSr@hN6SfMeEOi21@UIMrZKIBaaJsuLgJXiEuIPjEkN8nPMDBUxyg7AmktE05RtUeUG5zRWEBeqcaRpSUmzEemh959OnFBsLL177TZhGtVxqXJOrERR9eFZBNYaDO5yMpHiSoZVC4HumgrSvRvBXzOhsnrnfu2GUILGOgjxCggKDzr1wNG3c5VJMvq9Szm16PxIX8aBHzPL@3L1YFwbiWz2HqQj9X/JhYvW7jpTi@eGSATlkz5G/TAW5cSL6pR6Nzev4KDUG0cHwPFJdzDrQLYzz5B2HouiOErFOIwQM2mGbCq47NpF2ce8GMtYc1WCC1BzX0IbH7/9ChZd3C7pABuFXGQCm0wgIM1TmKbsUT2QG0TdKJjEeJnWT8UNrFWfZXvqZeGw9ws/Th/HfB5fkER2ao1RznPD2pUCK5niJSOBvT7mfqS4V77eo70x5p@o7Qw@/vg/Qw6/vLD1/Vn19i/E7qggMMfTAOQ5O2Z/BjBrfi@4FcjvFM4aBuWCE2nw/nXpo4TtdplLTdfyzqU3LMh28f3l@CXiecwpB8aFwyPMZz2MV3DBBznLzkVzOQdfD286dCO/iton6YpzcTfjh4xfokzq3bYsxmgIQc4Us@r43PeWHDBJiKAkHeSLRrx9mxWUqVydAbbum/cU1Fsqq6hecKsrnYIwS@7VPMO4N4QhVnbYvQmm8JEioBJuXZIh6B6abToJh85MIqgv5OJkKqc7mpvIaEVOL3ZWeJkRiR9rls6RA65ZCa01Nks7AriF9wp/H@vbeUdJjcN4YZOmNJb1RGqZiu12ytm3wjdjsUFin8NgTqPBu3zaHvT7Di6JQB0RYvqW8a6J2j9olaPX4TsMh3lWz6m2LiwfV9@3HWXZqMZjk0/l57LmvD9kGKv6tMdqSuS0gHhomxA6rhQVPd1oITNoLJOl94Etu6OMWhyB7arNQATaRH6AIr9ESB9kfETvNydgbxNKyr4FIiuuqA8tFzVrjVcDqB8ksXIYJEqIG4N3xRcrKgg86v7CcjUOlpdKFi7sHrDKvtLm5haRjqNOFbKlo6ss9UjhuRZy23UBxMHcszab6e2g/P1e@eg3z/i@wJmTqcWWK4FSY5OLmaFB28GjeQMMZi@IIToUZOKDcN22cG45TczHfoj2OepdyC3MvmiojXDIjitOH@ewNbjSam5pW3PoKNBUdHUBEUAJSrfjaGa6X4fuzMPVrmo76ifkE2CFVDu@d5cUw27jK7CWepYRttlW146DKqiCvUDnjeLxBdFdvlbCjKT2cIcJM3RO9XnHIHk2zxb7W5qcyNg6xKLb6cajZfLKNpclAW9K@H2CFjb7aviZYfFNMgD2tGWkgm@GmzS5zPg4VG00Ops2SMSciZDwfaY7ETpxpPUoIqOoEMHFebVYJCQGj@olXQU6xlWevQ1ONJ/Nosw6@7SHmiDc5CJsR0jZs@0GrSYaBvPINMjA86@KEruYQntD0O8W6Qx1lsWllMA4l4WRlwz5ULFtPavwSw4lqhjwTQFywTsaGMIptKLaPIU7DuBiJuaT5MnhlBhqzegA4zaH9OVaIvj7RgJQTdJtY3qFDQYH9AqLJfh5HfnM8mC7utbBVMYXANLlEijKZRUtD8SxWwzTSYcwcbBYxwCFY4mvbr/afqP0YKkAGyh4QMHj8HS2MbQWNlVR0MfuEnk61REYWVQE5MBjqrmKo5tDRx79vRogs0GsRhe4MQWPyvhfeSXUcp2F8dpbFlwGw3ewBbXfDvQk4UQfhnd9bxRjpRIgabLiBKcZZpotjME7Ke3cTLhPFTzBuT8Th4OjtCZiKwSsT0NKD2wRcOuOV4tsGQHTScTHDzVA6b4Od0naHJET7Jm6uwD2lQ7QH4R4PG4@IUZOgwMa6IHLTUm2eGXDb2Bwyb3wGfg2u@gQBGdy1qUGmYugj/CibsVrI93wgATyIO4QKtxz21FAaEL9QcAAn2xGU2xveWqqwUeDgxle38KWHmANlC0/ErfEzcEGGPzs3vgqHNl/MEnFPpcvhtQLQ2UJWMr7PPv5EzO8T3kR/av8TqcyercuD5Qwl9vbjSgLtqpg1y3kTWK1KGy3iWg13aqzhCQvolwB6rl0@qeFaC9@1QbYzbMVbYBBVsdt9qBK0l4YM49pEp47WIbLBHA7N3v5V5g4D9DXMlSvQxnDQwitpukQv/5gmrXugkRxA4gHqBOUcHL3USMJpSeDnC9zqSfbjTsLvWzwrmpfg5AcAfTsSjqCiTGS/FIRBf7CzyadONy68aArJI1nQfy4C8ZoScR/9TFT@0ru53p/y5avTGOVHMCYC49nUkTA0eLmhLU63pn3NV47Q7EaS31U0snvjWiDfsIyJPIseLvI7QRxfyfCMc8FrTag/48DSV9wvG3k9bnJBKOr8QA8/OBUQmK/hVYNNy/5u5BznLRBhbW6Byooo3BnF0/KVSy7Yfebx1ly5DZGfDcqFj24JWtfCXYG3tTBl8nNttt4V2tUEbwhIwREI7ZUcze/CJOnlkSY0BMULz@c4VPhkzQOriuNO6XDIPU7/eTk98gleUY16zuuNnD9qNc4dQR7@JuF2aKvukne8ge8nmyA/vZ@05r/A4efRjSQGN6dW2Ujs76KTViO@w2thav7NeI3PUSVdWBh/C3WIFv428cAmLxE3i25A8w5/M2Ce88bULM8TjF3e9eccVRGbPPnrDmB4Z/gyBXF8A7xhY7jjJvzletFBHTfjuMQ7oZE@zaUP8Pe8fqfojimuMqOBlSdyaL3w21ZivB7Isxf9rjXsYlFwpR/SBAdUZk@nPOn6Ioe25vIFf04pAqd9h0PEwft/IrRb0LtQn59aASg6siJW@EXCc88mjujFNuqusJHxGrClpshW1MG7wggrQQveoetsaFb1wlZ78DjSsEQdJ4b6kr/ynYlscmPi4cHu/snWUfNo6@3W0fEWpaSN/P6B4qGVJUuZc4uXexsCb8yZuBAncmZrMI7jiEPvWcIZ@HHbdF22DdNdFabj1wqkVIZq5ME19/zew3Gnjmqv8vQnXJmnw/e009jR8IjQELcqQf1u@QScLw/HnQRnfhgD6UIq3PWq400G/L1QEZSZIMx5DMpP7Ektk97fShDiZAMOKWbXvUUNUMwmJteYYaTRO9Cb1YzYY@tBo8khuC/BvxABFQCIx1234wy9DDrcV4HwKuicqEZiWfmLXGHuvZFjhzzbTcqWbfJ6oQ6p6KbRi4jbE0IlIM0NBq0Uvmp61SMxHQqCLHDfAt4UiJTmNeIVyuL8ICv/v@0963Kbx3W/hadYgXIIEHdKchSBoEiJVMypJXIoym4GgmEQBMVPwi34ABEICU/Te6edzqRxncbNZXpJ2mn/tp2kmekj2O@QJ8gbpOe2@@1@F5CSFXvaETUigd2zZ29nd8/ZPZdiufT6XBoEj9hfkbeCVzDJf0U776idfmz8pDizfR0DwOJx5iEbOidsUqwFXXy0JtegLlTRqlT0aubkydbkgv76V2xBnmBALq278eUYjb9ee@5Lm1l/YR8LX74ZTiwBO1Y5mnxjVUznr89g5/@K1cjLmYtcZEXxxnQi3nRCAqq9jPHE8soyaR8j57Gzyxf2eNVkrn98rd0t4YxCPJnetRxFWxPBxlWaD@LRiCby5ZToHQ16R638d6YOn9zXGFuAoLvxascv0WvLOMLpaPmlNOFNoJ4LVNxtbf25035dr622jyrtoxnynsFFGq45aa6rIk27zfm5ctTA2dKFdXyJ/EXD3Ji3aKfy1mWcVkaXs0PfmXHJkPo7XwrGlDZB3sYSI4vDa7kh5oRabZtEgStXHYV4kaOyGtc8On4htfVgBIPLUnIiZl/iS1szKzg2GIiKzga0PciG58hBGVzGJqF0p0bPRVJlstAiNiHmBf7/i7WVIUE28HhjZPUVGlm9sRp5YzXyxmpkkdXI0tXSxB@VDr1@CVizriqcAvefWoIFtbWr3n9n80AdvLOt7j@@93vqW7uP1fubDyFlV@09vvvuzj0F/7cfPtpWVMD8vNcZocq9gqnf6rQ7dDu/Wi7fUIQ5EqD8hnrU6ql3Bu3OCyCeNb/V2zjhL8V@Z7zOpbZfdEazAT8HDVGZZSxWE3RXxG9N@sYJLa4PgZJ7@I6ofXliG8mbp883S2R7QeHQjQE3v@0RD0J6XPSsZIw2AH4AqYCmxU@ypDuNT@vEtBwVlQyc@XnpEQSm8MEjtflwCyN9bu0c7Ow@fKTu7@7D171voZsdtbWDbmPuPsYsAnywu7Vzf@feJiVwA8pFhXdrZLC@qAlFBKdRaT8/nmB4sC5KhfLN8eq9lEr1B9oqwlfLk37gvucISArf3dnZaZVctGeube5/8z3kajrfVuk0Brm0HKqLBcK1MhqNQG0SRbvKztSRtSxUeEPqzdQ1zK6m6A6IPueVRp6ld2Kvo9L38BoRH6QpbjYzbBo1VHQVcCMq7Qi2pigCw/Jyfo1QrkNtdHuga8OL1WP9BYtuiGNWlCOXtJdWn5BicMadfpvD6OoEoHvW6qZqxyMGwAshSWAAvIPBhHHreWcHL0nUTYGYjFHwh4S3OeFZb3j/FLlGNHCVhLscCOSWtInnjaYUAxy1vD7Po2PWxLsDxUihIj7Bo5OcbldfuZJKHPD/8saGr7IAmYZd8BhWthYqgmc3oAbY209ax2NfZWpZvA0GEaTT91hT62m3BeIe3QuP0GDpBaoRULW3avizrh3Va4aTAnFqEeZwptx2mHJbcvB3LlsOSt6N1Ih6e9RpVJiS@E8XNuBupAGvggYQFez9At0KDcfE2BKawbGQcsYfAEWCyKc@cqMaDY4m7Y5TQGSdzDPvO9/JyiDngyKWig@1zmjYYagHfAg5RR9U5OYChBjSlDzB1yiew4zbg@BtuIfKECNs4Id6cKU2W3jQNYomjlSK/HxCrYctMoa7sFaieNYNNtvX0PiMoudvn83y6JnkEMVkI8356M8ZlRjQs9MI3bwcK1Qsmo2pJRzcIRXsHR8pv1T/4FZtfevuk8JHH@YbpdJT3hZaR/x4wUqJ/MxCIjksD6M7SdqAeqUJ0pQ/OcTSWp@Rd0tc5RoZMC4nHjDfG82qyeNr1Wh6n@JluemUeH5e41IFsjchEsJIMsHulld1XWWeyjRUVhAEeyc0Fj3r6pQ84TT79QbGtcdZqMKI9HEfIfUaO6wa6ddY3q7xQQ92lpTwaTzdBn9WxyIXiqKfjD0fpQ8yd2u59WxJQ9FiMsOZ0Vt0XmOuZKVXc5xeOq8i6LYWo4P9@/Lobi1sHR8PL4VtayG2l2pbIZeMi48lC9fl0X60AC0fbq@EFvqeT0bMh2QUm6F0Q5z5a0ua5i@o8cPI3NHaAzR49mJEVYPUqm3S76KHuAxfikPTqEDWRhMwRI8Otrb391V6G2/ZbkNZ2Pda/TbZl@I2iLivak9HbIdMm13RME0mTJBhnnTKnM1L3WoXLebYwUvYKoQHyct4mM3CRO0FyWQq1hF8shALgYbXvCHqkXNbd6b3IL8uiOd11IRSwaRZHUzFdnOJDx92sk@bTDBueeaN/efe0DAznak466Kr6tHMRqQZYTwOWk/x5Tt@/t5n/vi2rocZrM63J9RhVMJvo7989QgqHuJLcdGdwQXToqeUdFaISpf02JFZnsthf3GCMrHY58ILW9u6MMfSNOaPr1mR7Ig/3cB3/plktnty36m3eEpZsyc0Gxx6GfcIAiYTxGC1YVMFFG/M5Qij0TDnZM0w5PZau0atqetWUjQzwV1NBnoLOPibb4e3h3BVsNsurKrweqriU8KpyYq7Fa1BZwLmt2/evH4R7nAvdPHCF8XNZ0h4/xz3hi9aFkp/5pOqEFDuzsO8zg8IYMHQ1UAKPMroBRMqCKxOzJni9J0OI7t90JbTEdriQWN2Hx/k8b4oXGtWTUNti8fOJ5KNnUAifbCWsOkor5rI6M8XV3eXgrpdUN/Vl6@PFxsC4X34/LccJnN/MMStEhjxUZO9ooJIfttHrbgxluDgg8bTrxUDc0PHsaxzvLkNfuFGG2mucWM8eI56/TpypsQ2S@MzVLHXGp6d4wXXOV2Zch7aBEhZL682nrGOCkfW3DgakBLBsQllucGtdNNgm3/RtINv3kb1QcpjAOsBs2YGcPlrywrkntt4q6BDTS7nOA34E5NU4CSg1THKHiZ9hdPRLsEbdmcmvcTpRx0MPGdS1wTLactEvFxeF8hwhMzltADTXa13PGvSsJvsO5wNbIxJeksaA7Jld2BSr3Iq6lTppLqUnQRJDU4CScokLQkUHkze2KYlv9N53qRJlmhzgHA5r/pet1EU/ak7GZEds2LCMeaJhPKd/lGKJoVinhpU@kjYQNeyQkL1Da9RJAVK2YBQJgsmlhfShhcUsIEh3Qp9yUTFxagB@FsaIU21iRdrrm88Qwofdfz2pKO2pyjj69iImirJMciS2n64pXbvq/3dvW0XNba4iTwKldIKexSKWRpG3dFLNg8TPpiMT5qcqL@Gc087nKtR8HcD1B@MLCD@Gs7VFRCKBi5LdXZ@dK7qcHgPzaRkjrINmXTdY9OHYnsw6Y/PzqfnNL1T4PSKQAJ31LyIlwR3IsMiK1E4bE0O9BaHYSGRr2xqtwpBLZRCtUzFN8dALK5Daz47F2wps3/C1MHKpE06CMgJ2yTuBANkeW5LfEsYjvZJEHCT3rJrKpMJNwwPpWIxkpxTXzeBGzt2xF23sktWkkuq5BtBJUxhBk/RxziiQW1ZdTRQ5965riw4VPDovxWWdsxoo@9mmUbriKFl58CUG1Y2v0pYfT5KuZ8iC05mULnxRuV1gxcEBnkPdvMa07gDRvQdATObgwbjBRSBo1XgAPIyiQBS@SjGZnwrg6UXUyS@xcF6jDYnoZYAXUyR@FqCRrtTEaz10Gy0B8CdcUAS/NAEQdA6X2NnDsgmUnHSYlXhgkKKJM40uc4M/8nG1KG3aYYAemzoj5UGm96oZbvYQnh3ROwWSOetAcE9iNyp4LFmp1fC6faRpNat4mEIq1EhYMAZOqkungv2JOIknaKlFi8rMtqSaODIa8nRCFtOwwIlEkoALbigvGoCWABFEOLi8GSxQHkluqC5eFCL@Anexhpqq7UaDWguHtRaHxGshTisLmguDBrZ12ijdMfeMLQrmcWTl03gY210VlWdaac9GfNJo51WwBoaw/KwGS2BPvKeeuM7KmC06FMR2oNEe@OWeMTWaSDg3/y6YX2ogGa17SZItQFC3C0sXsqLqZivo2z2LWDMDfPowHOIa3wft0DrBGFPg2IPTNIQzWSIQKNPMc2K2UPDpaZjVSVjJJVWS2fwdY7cb33pjMUdjvyezqez8zQ3q@rsotAnnSzy0dqaHovieND0VOxPVRpPOAZD5eIoBkkLfhwck7FJxSuOfHfQ5svOPOKqamGtDukogNPDTggHvqZE@6ILAprGxe3AB5UoDmxCTi3qlI1DC1VRHCuXxqEFtiiOwuXbQfJUXF/eujQOFgTjcJQujQMpMDqm6aUzQDDn3@k4UnPGA82iJLWVP3RJw@BsOd8Ow33RoqpCe0HC4MBPQ9/i2iGMuU3rXUsMutR4oNARHY@MxytpHY5i2rnLfMFcwZLZyHph4ZZS@QbWWnlVdc0fH8FBUDzumvUds/hDInrokkQQ0r0HCjHF9skIRCSczaJIH5oBIZzQ/mYTVbOaTboZ2tvf/eb@5oPmw80HKEQt8R6F1zeoLUPqOuXiKsaz59uWJukU1RSqWmA3UrQPW3nUPkGzTacIRY7FUktnFtw8zQwU1lSj@6Jiv3Oq7kMWBa2P4ETIormbgenJUBvMpp4uvEhnA0j7BNO9EnltHVpCMEwn0hKCsZJTlrDF5Z/0WUPlSf/JmAEPVZ1tMv2G3d4naLhkFVSq8OLJ@L3O6BB1SQrGaSnPIqrgo@xGzqlQ5UJu0AMM1gT@tlRSd7VTXLFfa3Xb6PJ2ckyOb3tet9U7PGoVhyfD1LFfE/c0meVjH51cplCZaudge/9Rcw/jdG3fI8sJ/KlS3sHOg@3dxweY8wiyrkvy9v7@7n6TFNT3H@8doMfQUFLaBhQsAZgkOEAPd9/ZfNeC4e9paSQbhPggb8IfceWTV96wOaXfMzLzyLMqRJOC8JCZChaltLwae73OYKKDt6H/CX3A59HyBB9loC4d1Zgc0mTw@lPyAl@ncwuK2jGaDMcEShrwmdBIZN0SDNPzn2IB8kXkA99O2vRFvlHGPDTkGwwzobJoIIPFUmLfdezT6sBl8mjWb2c0OnHkmT/r9AESX5uWJ@Pjwq3leRa9Sg5JaShceLkEJ0eJnKMux5eUERSt9JQVxMi@dq2mtME7QJFFCU1CYJlCBfgFsapyOS97lrIDREkW7KocP@pMWTb0LozEr7lizRG7NWU9X6gfCcR8EgscQyP8dc9@lCICk/cpMuaoo@W5GTP6qzvLN8wZMzsZep8K7LqLqD1yDxq8Oc6woxfy2RfQnTx3SQOamBGecTcP0MvbmHSYKmQa98dVGKjxaKbYgtAfm@GCnjfw91Rcu7ZRgSYDBJe1YdNpzmV3lGgk5I8ZgMS89Hr6duDGhs0SjOIwQ6zZEJU4iA9siNU4iBc2xPU4iM8@ZhDvOJPL6clbV6s3b7I2szOfMcX/wxQvFDTsmlaFDgoDPru4Po0ZyTbjEOhcDc1B7TMbkNste3thy1zUn/0n4LZxSakCVcINX9DsBZg//8P0bb6hu8Qo/R330NqgkDmRJy82Ycb7wntC4rpJYksaxvaLBdjSaT2L8WV/GFDEBwlE89kvHZh4svlEz7sy46dfuK4EZSuBVUMYwX9FEdReBkGTy@v1Rd5G2YAXs1dvGyy6BwECBrlug6yGQeKqPF9YZdnGV4mtsmKDlC9T5We/kjrl/IqB@ImBoL1WBjMW9H@chUaq@VAoDtRnSLSp2QtefRPBn7ptsIvFge8F2KlIY3G7P/9uuN1ByVj4P4olTipg05ee9tiB/6fL4rieiONDRlEoJI7bMkPkcokQn/0saAcPb3iZLVokn//JxaXLyaX/ICgdHPPr@uBmrkEjC2@BRj3IzaSidYON5w8GwKTEtMY6Rs2as5YcnsViMOZ2oGKyxeLMzV7V2bPY7OsmO4R8zgyW5pLQvx4xRmscYZBYo@AzWfkyw6Uz12s215blDtncLjPrYmAOY2N4HDHFsZie9ZDAseIIGVHUkpsVZm@eIi64Giv8@K1R66TfwgCt/qBflAgg3qC03Rs88/CgGpXQzUXxmZ8kDX0R1poQkBxXQ/F1ExUqoKniVIR1v1luR8BWuz3pTbr4hlYTuQodI5VK6DKOBMH@pOcLTjxx7068LvSghpxawCKCmDeEVtIpDKz0paoPVR1XbbTKUon1xovkho6SqG3tkTccU2W1qCyALp@IQYUqvDULVrPwaKB@RojYFW1N@vOu1@9kLHiM4urlrQTyi5CrcakqUUZ4TCwcedQAeTjpORjOZMZJN6bGOUUfLX4y5fwqjlwH6UaNOhghxFhHeL5aFR905FoGkYgF0cjFspq/keVRIkR7QJ49F@JGfrWMFQ0xi1wUkWdoo1neOia3RWTUSjgIm4GmWQCOMEAv47peht5BhmlXLf2bn378D@nsWamk0yimjtdvgcxAEUkCrPj1YLCnv1voUT4RW8UQ7n8McDPqo07b67UwQs3YQg3ElYAZJhAxnwGhodOqQRf2m8HTjOULRleIhFUqbW5tqYN39nffR2sovkQgKggVRyK4rdI5HnYq6eSLYjCCCCVEYR5IxQikGxGFMr1CMNNjcq9znLE0sGC0vvdnNFp0lz9ATXdelyGEmJ1mpz54T4i6tTZaMxGagnEevvenjHkwZO3ZeMSDYVoIEz4OO0D8@ioyE@kXQ8TX9@sf/SVVJxYlwPPhvUrPrjqJ6afculzIEs0WKo3EXjnV0CAkIr5wiL7/c0Lmc5BuvRGmrti7okES3@2f/K0iHPj4ALNnlVQOntyFiD5hROb1gEYuEV/hQnw/YHxHHr0C2IgOZ24XH8A5WRyh0VDGSi5dMHy//pG0GOC9Mb6ZLKhjxWluKnYy/t2eWSor05E0vxb@xBn@sY1UzFyTMPJBFYvn418Fy9TuJrtOZvq@Yq3OUNNiO/zxf8dRH@mYw@pBD@CM1p6q2LWS0Oa//huDf5q6Mr2AYH7z009/FvRxmtizaWJ/Pg1W0zTai2lS26@EtqTfxyMjnZsmTsUv3WqclTutWV@TEPwiadyn7mBPk5Y8kL5Z9NMLln0Skk80ErPgpxcu@SRcP9C4Yhd7uFsJy32auMw19oSFHsK/ktBMWIz/Zi/G6aKZT1zzyWTx94QcGT40Ho1MS6kkHE6ZWNs1VaG/6JkX/66HW2PvfnjVFjAuNeCoAB1KTQ7tIdR0zV75Z@GY8nPma4LUijhb0D2yaqlILSCatLp@TFW12muraxWHDsS9mFrWX62S1LxU6nfY6H4yPEKpg97veiR5jOj5D4MHxO@M36W5BG4bxBW2tiH3BHVqcoNecPwI@SA68jmkRQ30AH0E4gb9XTPdLVQ4heSNK2Es3QGzRFfoOh1FoURBRCSJXKURK1SwnBq7EP7F7EAsXR2ydIWDJX0kP7JBzoWb9/d/ZnYkM0oDF3sIZe5inP8s00AqRvRWTh47hKdLRl1zvhlByk3VR0Di0f2v9m4Rqi6Zl7TAkjD/8M/NQdfxUZf1CPqDJq/k8R@DY@LAJJ6A1v7JHwlBJrsSbBmJNf@Fnnifd6ikyvEku0Q9CdX8/I/TSNrxg8TZ1YuFLMGYKGOpnYfq8aPtfbX7@GDv8QFeyNiOEY0MnizosdjN@zIJsO4lQUSWrYKYv8rirJXH5OXlvdxqlrr/V59i9xltrpYup61hWljux065ii63YIxoKi49QjI@kfJ8aQGt47qlt7XaLRkhEKB3@mNcr34HPggYX0yww2c525j82WTalrqlYsZzial/nd2yLmOSLxPwqMMJqFUUzl@t/IYyvhzKoCurGb7e1eJe8xg/9EK7/CTQL5uCnJvN@Avf09PT4jGGp5qMvGLHR/dEPjqGKw2fArPQH9ClJrrNBsLz2iDbovPCSft58KnQbvVftHxUkLkzRZXo2je@NuO/qaQ74uHTHofieNV7YqXotjc/y7fzgCx/2H6ePz49qkoGGwYbhRNORO5npL/0fP3JGx4biMEY79lN1mH3eXvQJW43fdiFgywdVM091JAz/VW@Dz02jNGXyDPxfqqIac6wIoXCRwPKgY/AVWnrYm9anzWc4lNT3NFm8Tki5kKkrBCM@azHQWEDppw/DSrV1dan4izemJDh6wMqhWhIRDPTMI5FOOZMWSl@HV@oMA0hZ04aWv60a1Rajzd/g3msacIAmhjCgHcypfoHT@pPGn2/c7rSyJWe5tHREUIfilkjjSn57OHPOPrdF93hwHeS@h1/zAouZZ3UPhFqYFphxRcZq5DGDTTLKNx4waChdmCNMnGL3hxnPDFTJW2cE3reTtfTwRhzw@rSGBxpTysZSBo@PFmm9jaihoUI002XdCS@OF2o9Psj9KelYQsw5ugApj9DM0IM1OAuFYlhquZuq/C1jBNg2NkHbqgrOh@moh7Ksro5l/m3m3/1pZt/DOsivvVEsLwphpTGph3YcDuyXNgj5nrNmldoQWml1UWXf@ntPrmn0YqD2epKSZumcD3YBQk6a01@WxxP8EtqX7RQsK4Zyr5qVuNlyetCD6nRNAle4SlfE4KU5w2EI4jEFOtIsaldDCRd3jjoWSyu2KnVyCk1cspFGHqa0MiGFMNAnrbbhgY6bWvBeQT4KqzRS2Kh8lsvMD4VuyJaKZk6gz2HqEBbGMKEIp21G7G1161GW5tWCAESYgTBUee4NemOb6fCG16lYL6ZPYqHUu9R/E3IgPcKIDDagqusVJYxRCYvFniV7pHbS/hUT6Ur@XK@Qv/K/D@d14n6fyWaWHYhK25iOR/69ztJbODIxotFlfIN3JBT/ws';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        86xxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print((1/2and 9or 13<<65>>65or 68)-(0and eval('\'ppp\'.bytes.class==Array and 4or(\'_\'[0]==95and-91or-93)'))^1<<65>>62);exit;"[$'#{print 187;exit}]es##print##es'$/"#wWWs {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ye{--}besizeString tnd xfmain=los1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"cl91/2 <5>6#"5"8=2860ay =+ codefn( );#6and [9]=x 3 8[]p#s
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25        pppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

Run the code snippet for a TIO link.

### Explanation

This polyglot is the same as previous one. The purpose of this answer is to activate functionality already added in [answer 183](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157799).

To run polyglot in [ZEMU](http://www.z80.info/zip/zemu.zip):

- Disks > A: select polyglot file
- Options > Instruction Set Z80
- Press Boot button

How Intel 8080 interprets the code:

```
    org 3120h

    mvi c,31h    ; '1'
    call cns$ot
    mvi c,38h    ; '8'
    call cns$ot
    db 38h       ; NOP in I8080
    mvi c,33h    ; '3'
    call cns$ot
    hlt          ; halt processor

...
```

How Zilog Z80 interprets the code:

```
    org 3120h

    mvi c,31h    ; '1'
    call cns$ot
    mvi c,38h    ; '8'
    call cns$ot
    jrc somewhere ; no jump;  Zilog syntax: jr c,*
    inc sp       ; harmless
    call cns$ot  ; '8'
    hlt          ; halt processor

...
```

Different behavior is achieved by using `jrc` instruction (jump relative if carry) which was added in Z80.

Carry flag was cleared by last `sub h` instruction in the generator program (see [answer 183](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157799)), so `jrc` does nothing.
`inc sp` is also harmless, so the code just calls `cns$ot` with the same parameter again, which gives `188`.

Generator program consists only of Intel 8080 instructions, so it is executed identically in I8080 and Z80.

Answer (score 6):

## 189. Haskell with BangPatterns, 9389 bytes

I couldn't fit the answer and its TIO link so I've opted for [the link](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9KFJklUol3dK9VSW1pKq691IsVpJMillKZvJmkhJZKl302EbvPBb2bk/voLfHO7d7vIYH8AI72LWBXcwABrxfF4P9DXc@GQPD/Q/a55yIfPEhqbpnvKZEZmTEiRMnTkScOPE60TL83m9@k8IPO3LtybntDtnQ9Ies41mXpqexJxP22LD89eKqJCHUjnc@6pvO0C9LKaYzZjltqwPvbOhemI71wfTAv8jYwHPPPaPPhj1jyEy/bQxMn7mj4WA0ZG53frRVxvb67nsrhzH7lnMOYEPTG3jmkMLXGHvl2Ea/1TGmQtanEhx4EO6zp6b9sf9xyNpuv284HR8gNxh74Xq@ifBt0/ddjL7J2HjPbE8hLQGo4Vnu852Xn08FbTH2OZBoDGxzzIyWP/SM9tByHeRJgZ28fHVyNBVD19nr0/39ad8i@zLnOmx/1L6YDlplrzzfsI1p/GtsZzR0D4bT/uts59x0DFbUtrTidOAGe@IZM1E2mWcana5lmxoUCMuxnmkPTI@hD@u6HjsAkuxSoVRo7kQxtTbGLUWB02i3mL26OpzKT7EAjHe9nukAhYXpQD0MnAoohgEdixIwvAlT/J7rQT3y2Mg3O@zK9TpQuRx7omYhPht/YC3DNzfWEMFqiODCca8cqERDF4q2NRmazHGdHEVGwDWmP29OV6ziOvruHB5M@2@w4vNpv02oaO2L7mxZFkvs2B1Mpn232Avr@bzqvFrgDWHX7UBpTIXp7MgAL0omznhqnkee2xm1sekMeybExOaGpelLbSj@GhuIRq6hg6Wo/DkYoD5x@2Y8NZ85JrDXH5htq2u1ebUwx0PT8SFBX2MWkHBl2TbrmDZEiLC3s8x3sXAir5Zt9LS2JmG1wlRY/8JmFmsPBowHMdsCkvYLJWZi3tkHCLd7PhsP@sy3@hA8bLvdrmmyD@agB9Gljisx@LQHU9kK35ZNgHHMgDXmAJozssbF1g98Cjh05RkDqPe@4MHQ6oOwsoZpn5mGb6E4hCi@6XSIq4NQULrMSFRYdmlBc4WsjzzC7ZseNRjCC43LMwGlEYoq5cqzhkOq82yHHZmGx04901STQjORJCTmYgpDzIhGhbq9nd473E9D4fIYmjGAwvRWT3/0hWQwrcqWmxX4VmW5Iu29fMqul8/QzWUkVICBpxgqq37H/PzZmQnfsd7Kn3s3EmCVgCs2y7uDYd7IDYDA3BAIzBvoRFfusqgN7FjCbHuqLGJVjkN1oDRAdLDXWcpZe@R52A9ETDUuINO265wDPyGz3shBfjhsowBF0HZBjGeZeQlcA7lJZQStGjl82rOg0Hwskliz4L0ZMRT6M6jGgqNBur5rjwgOYvpDrMvAFYiKGA@67DXrGpaNUSAcUXGqPdMf2UOMM3I6WPLQW5kdjQVktKHhAlDfvYTkDEBKHlD1@7F2SUQBMBSES1nFoB/@6Z92zs8Bz067DZJJVNfXrOO2qd81iFjozBhWWBCHNpEFcFlMnUeHBC4N2@oYQ0zemYgkiAhK9cod2R3mQoLelQWttGdcQsuGxtUemryS8646y/rGBZcmFq@5kPG@0YKCpQQobcp2jj3ehVJqm1KK6kyuPxp2Syw32GNpP/9WeVRWHi2dmUCcqqkry/n8eQUqnLZCXvCWvq3mvN5JdDD@0PBdqyMNJsOe6xRZrs3kdtUdmI6STuBIZ9NeK61qKOUUtWJV21rXcjpKehvqYg0STquVdrVdt8qNylT0eJKA5grRYHM1lbYqSyByqFFc5vsgizUQ7a9zwhULc/0mshyDtZg3Mmba75J7pEhVwXrpYgUBOaT5tmkOlIKmqygmEG5uvjFgXk6ncIgMl61GJp1KZ@JZJwyQ00RGsbGeWi6KLXvQwy4HmOL4A@gJPKy7behnUTL61hD0xSxrUb2mXgQkC8nEKzPtmdghh/WImiRvchg/h4JSYIiaULIlm51YQwYhAG156M9IY9u9ggSJJuxmQHQ4mKhxDkUDkXlGdnhGeErkk8wSVxMAW8tkpVzLgkaAzQ1kuqjzsbwB@GqRwwA23khisqdvTABLm3erUYNhVhfaUh/EA@gybRNlDggfk3comMiI2p8PGjLqyoVccX092cZmmtjQy@/kvgEh/SF/a0vCzO8klAboebrmFbMN53xknJtcj2JGu20OhkJQQU78IYii6f6GPHOi89T8nrT8eDpt6kQC1SJKA4U8Lz3RFRooXYSanrNBmDJDDDRA7/NALNmT6dQB4HIqcfkdgiQIeCcvICHQAKCSmWOzPRqCVIMKfNWz2j2os0idw@Ui74SmkweveOog2XPdMGkkRq89LEpaPvRCMhaiyGGJzuKBzhVR1RIeVPhxj9sxG35/DmI3JBE6gpivljc0qHt34Oy7jjsHKTAyRIsgyRBeDqCJnaBCCR1XoHZRYw21zLCIoMxQje9g/esNhwO/DP2ENeyNWhrUlPypNzkYHjpYWfJDb2INXe5u2W4LxLIP7TMfpJBvj1rWeCpD5BeW4XtfugQFrOuzKvTc346g1inprg8Ck/x3ETgWJJPgJhT8VwZAAtKAUUrXJ1G8D0LlZOK0FVmjpqRBo5OzTMaGK8NgRcZYIV923T5KIfaGFAPU9GDQZjmo6QuZTyLfmNvVhbKf9Lp0WnvvWo5ynV5aWkqX0zWQ7EtLj8C1ja5H6MqA6xG5cuRCOA1dFCNLLgytUwz0a6Rv6gHmsdrAYhtjr/TBGihGvVxebWSNui6eRXyqIOpAsgF0Dh@AJ61Wq@hUVbl2BRnVWt1k7ndROp@0PWsgmPCFcWnwd8GFVWKD1R/gINAzK9jJ3s6TftWDXhCU1nZP8dJn9cJZ4@z6rJM5u0lnMbZaMaotyBSkp/S1c88dQXep1tfKOb2hqvVV6CRb1XQhvaIopZwNCRmq@llJzRic20raBKmtnJ2lgamCP/V2zyN842xRVUNWAR3YMYNOqKS16xKk31IbaiYNcdV0FoYY1XQaONNGJviUaayZCQYdHn/JGbObyUhUDV3vAr8zYh/8NBhg8ej7UH93T5KD1v4FSFfW9m1URXIe10bgNb/CPTv0CDWuMjsgjdWB7hZyAL1tJxwZ4VjaGZH@TMqtG0@IhoMIQX7Y96BctRIwiLhrjWGAAO1@EihC2H@jLrQLA07XNrU3pJrIDBoOw@auzdWGjni3orX9qA6A3gPOgW20oWEn0Z3J7AwQQj3P5@eHqJUZxNOqEo1q7sojdCxtw0H@dSzS2keW30P2gmaFQwmvC1xFlR10A5O4dsDa0OefA6fNsTXkOjzUoxOM8szwFRW1xh2udaGyhxoDEhXMAVB37rZhvGOC5oChfPDI9pxLy3MdZLK2B6ihwlewDKaQz2MvVKOdnYPi08X8nYccODbjrcd4G8c6zdy232Z5x7Xdc5etAABWTU3jFfvAaQMJoPMNYXjJfOsDMWjn3HUmU3XQxO7eRx1R31gNtW8DIfMEr70HWcPmZzoCWJDnk4Nv9qCH0NcLBaA/eCvQJ8xkDMt0HtGzzSIAMeFqY73BkvzGHPQmiekgrB98FAn1yTV5w@TjegM6VKBKtPAPFDXeyLkPtPMgqBO45uV9jzQknMqIjzISuQdlENqpyA5vNpDD1JQ3@gasSCCdKfCofPdBdp72RqZktnsuk89AwyjWWL5jXuZR4Mgg6HqgKucgKdMjZSyMJiaApaE7Aq2uY9pW3xoe0HSX7aDqEnXLQSjOuUUIjixzKInxRiRecUoqkrXOOYffG2OH5EsmPdnLw6d7zaOd02dVOT/yvbxttaAGd8xmHxRP2/RlNv1JsWMTkIn4Hy7sY9cdVnlxXdjszk8K4wTRnz9tPj94crxz/DUngtD4Vn9kG0hKeXkKAKOfUHDQqmLzgF3P7YcauS8KYnkVWW8mZuxxeCpC1zB0JObrY/4b6N/HOXitLZ232yzn8tfQUwBuIiDOy1Mfdp7JICTN04eeArJEKHGuXvNagecWeoaz9In56wjdvPDFkQTma71wg8h9Z@QPYjm71nXyvxx2u9hrh95F8r7IYVW3I@9V8uaz/Mn5dcGWmaC5wCG@NcLHVwfm4psJmgsc4lvn@HBVYT66qZB5oCGyDUKGqxBzcU0FzAEMMW0SpvjKRRRWorBFyxYirbnBCyOFuLcINy5tRKhooUN4BYBFXjv6fNnBb@IcaVRHinoiFIP4YgXLdWBwso0gWF8@4jIGeIEW5w862nA8jFCsxlHkQOfgixhhOK8Iut00mtAqI2oDn1gQy9kgwPSNKPJ6GNmdiupakXcIzsu1aDdBBIxiTTrwiQeFkXgRBqsl8UZR5CXouYNJrC1fFznz@5YQJ7HWtcrZTXIItSMvEci5PQhWTEiZ5gLuFLrU5y4oQs8tn9Yk4xJPChX2M0kORh0J9VqOQorR7B/LXc6ftpTjiEgWg7i8cHGwG7maBU1fRywhiv6FPRuzCzoj/SRAZ4iaDeF9QL/VpZ85AGUxIwbdHS7xIFe@wFl9nLRzQYM3rwiMxvaEDLhlOUb@mB44yp9HT3K@IkFMy@yOQLnNw@AL3XeA5bZKBNlttaxFoMAXJD14zgHzRq15bINW2JuZ0mIJxg9H3tA2O@L5n37cgQKYLZ6eMSGFPnQ0gW9UN7oLS0tExRf6mV@yBPN@ZFsGsYFcd6FsG7iKYNihYz5q1ExYLtczvD7qzaJwoXLiD7SaW@oZp9wz7VHHDJ7zEyEWJyfOeGzH6lOO4IkDPxrmLog@Ne3H49PQyXaNDmHhAxzLjEqbl4s55qp@TIMGGXMPOoPZORYthw17o@GI/@IK2F3lag3wO58r5WQlK6wbLd3Mu77Rssxb6oFnXIw6bm5wcU6ZRtI2FtV23ohwMinXtY0L7myicz4DeBY96/zc9ILnIrCrHujsNNjIX9HjlqoSaEyMdGDjNpyezX8XgQQ7SELHYj5ZNv18SoWkKtKGVoOsxWXuXIxN1hRjbaM1wUFX79NrFiZIqigInmo7kymsYt8ZrmlEC@qDweL42OFS/K2t@bH5AjtnybyhSJ4vrOf4hBPlWSy139Hqoeey@oadK3ZizoVCPJjMjFxzQGkEnmvbhg@VaSiKw7yE4qOf2yo4dkZtrFaR65bqHZETLG0tWiWJ4gxAw7Atf8BbnHhZJE2n55cjNLjTgX6iqPg2y98OKbl@Lxe65gsEtz3ElYoF9e0eAo4vEuAyTKwCae4i3rXdK/wuVDF67qXJf@d3eh/mUnUPUZWzqWZY7TnRO@27qiuuddPPfC5ezKVq2Lbn@osZ@aSaf98K7Vu268N4G39vYwRozr7Pf@dX5TjPLMPJ0cRx3D0/miBqwDQxUbagJA373LU3Sud5A34WFvfI66L4F8/7ir1QbOn63WIr0I5cRxfPhfL@Iu9d3FUTaHbZw1WomPOWznae7BKrF4szCGMIXFqen7n9Qoliank@@bGoALx278qYBM/foktZxN2gSxlMSLcG5Q8jbJXAMfS4vv3bpLZ2e2qd@wmkGbSbd2UiVrgXtgnimX5nipQVC/onxtALhfuLp649MkfmXC3vsPXexK2BfJoWdyQYts2XN08PDj@RqILIxrKYJswD83CSMIT6IEaO96IaO298u1XAGLYFjfxOFWeuvBuAQj7AwfYROI7QMRvx3BkNEoUb493xyDm@nXO9QdCy3U6CSAz5VIlUuluRSujsvknfRfr9Xt@F8bHbB4XBuUf5C6Q0o8F/E4jJJ1IzEhMfc5MPl6pBoQXFA0rUuvBzOOd9P6FTXDSoJ@CtLRi2OeZwgr@LOD1PiLZc1/6UkgFZ2rFoC7Cdw22jd5XQjJIjdi2waPrCx6mQVnfRxAXvZ8QIE7iHo@nhLePn@DTTLUPCmSnzW3qr2AT6XYNM6KlpZsj32oF7UYU8xkatayVt89bqyHVQt2XaBn@MN9Zuw7elrd6KL9Q6hHJLCy64SMOXZaJ1rdSU6BlMgFlWBwYoPbNv0ustmr3ReT/yg8dCoLGL3znBWp4WGRbEG1jQ1h38TSwBxbShoevAkGpoeOcmjklsXJsUvovka7B2MZe5B33j3OQnBG4THdHUBG5n4yO5yDl/kqLMd5i0IRpfgL@9KkDDuTAnfvCci/DFpA3lOerfim1eG2/jDOidjVrLz12yuUPdc3puz@mZPY8aR/i2qHlAjRzysx23ZQLo7xn@Be7fI3kUjeV6fpy7tmvb9@EuykMuHV13/uTsHu6970DUT8I7MVoQIB53zuNBl01Mor57UdvpmSPomXx36A7MHL0tArVxxof/zp9vPjhM@@yNZXodvvkAp/@ModWyTXZlAQnv/fiK9/zZpJbtGrhF9BblHTgTPO8zP9V2vTsnP84NdzgY0KM5sEc@/dA8b647fwKzzPaJ0vtUBmvI933wKmueu612z7qLpJZpDB3rIh9M5PDXW8elQhhTzi2We4remm0Br7yJhpWgGg8/wcfBov4vtjwzN/e7I8@b3C0Ykqv54XwrXyVAx6L0xcLrnGDq8nFjU7CB55alCrFOu7A2kQKNynLOLIBWoi@c/0ns4RLSixYMFyg9U/kmYmJrZJ8yfykW@mkmz4ptVgD/eZMXiwThMyHfYFSoPBud@@rdFbfXAZ0Kf@Yi3DnHw058Ncm33avYbDM0fcMRj7m9criieNvCyPqtKyPz2KzlxdpmzhwtnO@yrYHPf1muW5xL3uxi/SzUZP7oVxRZx@zy37s0vb7r4cZ2UClybc/02zgNjtKYS0kughz3HKRyzmYRcAA7l/zZvQHzdJVkj5f76qV5buBGt@cW7nmz/dlOEDBPbxO4D@IfjQzf@tHIHZpzcU5vF7gPyhfGudV@liiBAGHAXbErij8SjQK9Zgviqmf5tL84cMxvSLyK0cr7bOD0THt4zu32iZGYniS2ebLcAQu2g4YOnOvHcGNuWkktVCy6LxR81pAmUMVzbj7nb624bVbhatQfjHzxmJ96H08LxOeR@xfk719ZIBVz34IQZj3DHs6fa45NpoJ@JXrGyLlI6/7Gst1z9k2pwEAdA4GHSviCivUE@ukjYwgtwJmtrHyzwTGdYgvPO/hZsU0P/CxPHLbyteBEY4q2NNLph2A3PEvhmYwRSvWh62mM4BTFyGRUVeKRcF783AGwAIrOlOF5E35czWe25Q8J1uqyep0tX4/LhbJ@w6pMLsus0eBY8UOnH/bGAzoQdsyj15eNRnU5ncull9NnTpkV0iG4aUN9mAtuJGC7Fj04vRELmGPwjavoDnJc4edp/B6dVQNdqAM61SuHpjpQP@OnQviRo1NckP@Pf9ERR/hg4OWDMgLyGBiCJ1jdvtlzrx7xdEXqO4OBgUcAEQc0X5sfSMnt7jCoV6B88ZN77hV7tX9aEueBxHFZeDninXNIBS9cHP7jbt4hLzxOTbgzUyQcxgoy1XbtUd8Bdbcz7PkaO7Foo@7Ii3bcgQvBnKGHOn8nyw5Yx8RlT9p/TcNc23Uv6CAFUvIf/4KfgqJd2GJ3bJA8nX6MpYibrXU6etRuuyOgOkDywfRcAaIgk6Exj3ACCbp8k/uruDeZjmdBjcwFh5MoGX5CaXfnhOX2WBpPAuOZh4rVVZZ3jj9/XS80qt@xft78Tz/Oq9eCcfJnua0NX86yAKRygxUrHrwOwVFomsnLY5knGG5Rt8QW9SteHsAig1cy3KUe1DHXHYhWQwdM6TxlWBuFmQIF3VTOwSmlPp1NpQprXtEpJdoa6qCQw0Ofjg8NDF5VQs1bXXVZGfF5jtzJkK1DgnjSywAXP81Km7bxxA1GWR6zj6yHlSzXxo3E8MYZaeMhr371SbAPZjW@Wyn/1GyNaIn@sqgVV6uUneVmdbtGLs/suHjYsv72bFws5M7Gm3uNvB8w9exs/Fmh@BVw3YUh2PLDPLa8vZdPr5e1WuHjR9@YMFm@SVf4jioQE8vXRwdHeyenO6evTqAUbgLxs@96fSOSNViLaGtwz7XpGCvwxbNM/xPkT/gG4IrClg22jeYVVFWK73olUMFrOScvc2dMNCVi3xF9XnzfjIXPAgiZ1rVYUKMOQDnGMoTKhlzDzI8GeBiXibjiQCHVMgtlPDagkDG4b22OLCVWyawKzMoBs@7JKrY4s4@43304dieW29n2aC4IcixMrx6G8yzOZcHN30u@B9BR/u755lhuzzfB3JJvAA19gzj7OwfPXx3vJaNBHaMnSd3q1rrY7s2FM7Y0PkUSnKCkkzEiIs4RVWUmUwT@Kjozsp3RModXJmRLCMd2n0emGkr0y1JUMYEzVTRA0qhwXigKUYA6SAWzNbUbvWuNYyQGfXQM3TXPYigE9uUQdUC4JgvMKTInoeEnyAZiFewKmt4RCXEhr9N@XP3JBi0Os4Z9NKibFGtBVxX2Oj6D/1ivFLiKDTZmojvTGyzHivC1TRhq9UJYtcL7KLbMGSEvc9rlkF40ZQA0dd4bNDSjHVRiwz300rYxwHPTAvolDIfK7NuRS6d7AmES6hdXqPgb3GoHFW3bwNzQqSFniGegg36L8B3sn1RRO@OqGcn3eJ0bOdhRAVDMhsbeGHR6qGxdkvX8ND5nuSsOfgddJc3d@eKgZ6gl@OzS8mluDwuhizqODZIScyMyjuZn6FwX27F90Ek60H1zYy2knGi0s5dv7805TE5BndRClTHLZAlh/ersQWDoSq/a0K2@45GXCY4w@zGc6e2lXA44d245zHcsGHENyzgFSZMGZTb0RrhQXkvPRAlIKJMr1xv27RjgHJMIZ2b@h3/6p9wMwtkQ3H8g3OPCE3j7I/HWBfc/CUJ0Hd7@WfhWhLef8re3eSyy2bPfM3RiOxcZ4/SFJYil9/rgiPk094nl0zfGMdaj1MB6ZDnAA6sPBX1J5YbgPIWoWCI8Sv01FDvUFShzVFlQS6H0TK@h4Knecj6PGj0OyDTaLWuO@cQnHfL9doTGLUCxym@sb6zpeSAydxkgpJN257g9kyNU1TLIOenSGlTftdq4mZ7JftuwzepGhZd3ftl4uyq/CwldBliJK/91BnFw/30YA8JqIpqybGR0FaNi55TW0yinOi6vPqDhKeQAEBW9neCoEqiQrmAV1E3HHA9JC5oEg5oWmiDCCRqTmzgJEOUAEceNJhimm1i04RL3p8canRYvBvkNgp0gWFmeVwHrb9nZ8MxpCFMcDCrTL@dURwfcfzjHPgevWXj2cNYwhDJt1gFzwx6fOC5uzN0HaplSzBdX8/qGGquhskAF9GLz/QgoocGCAGib1nt34O/s7h18cXh0MmPggCDT02Bplq5tZ85yWrbeCB3pkO4kU5/s509ePNkPWBmnKlq2Roho7XqazHmpTVO6IPU3fKfrbNoUMJOQXrgvYlooyu3T1o5Z7FFoPga4y3fYzaSqqNc39cZ27cxJzST/cZ7Rl5S2gpULXGc@mXxJT5OJJB4E@3dP0RScrwVnN4pyZNIoPFXC3yPvxSYKQsNykZ2CYKewRCcIwwOEkrZgDzHkXcvzpOiQPicsoBdkTUCqjqRGCbalma0HcWqYyMusDTxxRCZk0iGfFwosmPkc0ifhzGeOyFhIyLMQ7jTAiE0/shwgjsz3gDrbaklX4nRncMAoPNmp@QPbGiqq5AiI6aNGs5D@rQfwQzCjWh@z8GyNj3rgWCOzLQrZt7lqSNx@AQvMDGTIUsHRCPh25A5YNDP21Axcx6AnsacjSKKNg6wvRn2A69Lj2MTewgTNKQeRgZ/pgJQ6ns0XnND6nXVlrGo9c9yxzqHHUdQsiKbPdD2ycWDgIX3QlVrzcoBTTYOeAXnAolndRhMBY3V7i16jDPKVE3Y139tpSIAMo7bUMp@NSL9yAnM0WPBlls6GnGmp2bTG@OhIWJqh5VOaXNLYbg83m9F0RrdrkRoWPznMO/Ou5fU1zBV0M7wKfY5bTeO15pPMTcQ4Y9QNzXI65ljBk73lBvIJ/NNXby7TqjxTxcnmhbBw0Jk2fhHIQmMohFJkOGJK3m1thXIuKRq2trSeL@EpLRhoQIonQ@85OEFFULp9Y8CUEVkP8ZnG6FU5U5ysP/RUlqthd33FHJbJ0DwFPCgAxiEI2iWXRce0FTS2peSrUEjo6zsdfHywBqyua1oD3JSIypZxjnIXtCmc3VMlGHdClDKhBf0C/spIETdsqAkDh8uUrEQH@AFqbjDJqfMeyRfgBeWa1R5Gp6VjAoZzdWurLEojKe23GNSL7TkCEdDOkeKB3g/8FedsgGsoowFq1zM7FsjLx1@ajmMCg6DO9NGOozGCSuap2cDEaDYyIkYppDiJz8TBHSA0aVxsL31tu6CuLecrNN1VuQG15t0Z6jVdodlM8v91XstXrpVluzrJg66p1pTlXlXPrK5kMsvOirLsoLb18CHOkt0sgzLX1GDQOQag3LKtVqA@g/JXXXYqy8a2stypFlcoBrzCsPcaInzn57XrZeMmv/wQlKUs@Hhc6CjLPtn9KGiafgP0YQtZzmehzlyjAQsyHIrJL1uZDNKgLTeRgO/yZycZ6jbPTvI0IVcR@n3@vC@a25QqFpbEjMFTzkDhXQ47rHXssMT@q2YAHJkWW50XtkD94wl/ibtUGS2um358QCUnQ@4vWIScRpkrhIzCDa8AA8cKMBFfs4aqgjD5zW9S@gZj8qONVcXNPFovVDLpdR2G3jBmTj0GPTy/Invy9dnT3CUzc@l611jXvm0cXRwdfaWeKWyLpVO7h7K@Jr9lW0V2v88mKy74sN/lk0qt5KVUfkV/uJnPv3v3DkYc8KnXtBqID/5R67l0o65sMlbb3FzJbpRWso/TzRhhqlIsqicsz84syxr4nQ583R5Z@VVS/PPoEaUFQ3r4Z9xPpC8cwQuCCN/Up8IZ6yl2tmkYK5m14mOnAqRt4WeV6eDE3xJ8dba@zvbw8zf/29/8/G9@Rn8/p@9fGeyCfYDPRZfhP7k/dGJuA92t7ge0iwJDiyrJhUE6vb6aPnmbZv@ffZaYXnu0@Z9/dvhtapiqFfNvPHgOU9@mNkop7gQHvK0Gb5epWmobwTZuUpN8tVoF5@Z//jcQv/YF4MGQyTb81NYDXBuTVC1XpSgfU7UNcOjFIqT7f/34x1KqNk59SOm6nprQXzNV0PFTeqg/ZAwceXmzJLvu44De0sY4/AR@eV0vnkXlGStuLNrQuwfpQLkyN5UEJXdYq5ioDeT4FDg0cbux9PjdU8ZM6GrxUy4/nmH486n3Yy0HH000gzG@5MZBFlKlarbJkw/rairmmMpw@MtE3sP3T4STUoE5x1zd6DbYOPY5S@mltcPH43t/WER0wMRUxLswcTbtF3A9fGFBo2efAielvqtWj4f496KFf0cn@Pfbijn2CD5L8Ef/8Alf8XeJfIQ3gcx@ln6H5iql6ql6o/GjHv15@PfMwb/Wt/j3/AP@/WiIf6dt/Dv@Ef4tyoyU2t7eTmUyx6Aaijp7n88r@GpaU7wFdRfR/b1@2NrhxuFjiaVyjUzu5qauvR1nKhXxD0pTJXzDD3cBWY2bXG77bS2TqRN59ZqgczvXqAGtnGT6ebsNiDPb9e1trVmr1XKNt7X6djKSiPf4cQbb6WOIWGvU61LqGsuiij8r@NP28bcoy3l6xc4CeuctcDFy0kN4MLLDju9S6t32OyXzKPOoYBcuC/qFfvHCPYz@Dw/HEGCNC@9dr9Ar9PQOSERWMF8VJoXJuNB3D/UOOE34K/TBaRW648J5wSk4uj4ZJ1At/u8fusMXhy5gcyHmcFwYIuJCF57nh4cvAF8X0n4Pf1ahUBgDkePCJfwXbBTUZCSKnm@b6plUZ/I7E3p/TU9rhbS2kU5bjfWNwbdn1zfFjW/lbLp5Vk83Kqm8f3aW59oRK65VyETYzU2zuffyabOZx3q0vZx5nMk9hk@1ltkWj0epWuXRWTmH5cfrn9ZM5bcfndVWc@jeyEAhFcFvO5/5xE@EEp61pTMJBnxv3uD3zdXlFXeRg1xnb96EofiTRy9ykRd8ADQ/N37CwUDT/Af67xz@/@v/xSum1BsqY8r1zbZCHxX/VPX65vpG/NZURREvyjb8oQe8Y5Trmxo6CegaXHVFbag3N9wPfhV1myOsYRrbNYocAUKDTfFUz9IV0PCqy4pYKDs7GxcKaqUFPuH0uvGR1lzUCu1GWW7hOhmMBvQVlUDW1yqVNeHeLFUqJeHWNzYqlZUQqgAvwglApm@0K1jRKykVSeBjA0XPF3FWZQsGXPrq9vbGeq22sQ4vGyU1pxQwiGw0ps/Sg8HgLK3R9LpGx9Sq1R3PMyY0K7MG470zaF5p3KFS3VpHe7RbuuvltlbVtKq@1QXqosppkOvL6RTfocL00iZ53jRMP5Uiv1TK9NPLeTkFtdRn1zcp4hZbW1eV1sRU2dqGUspsib/qksq287UVJv7q9dXM2srmyuNGI1IDsFFXro2qflO9Nso4pL@ptIXNQtyxZjx8uLr18aNeKlTOpGbz6c7pThONv8sySswBY@hL8kHC9b2Bl67TBMz6VqOOxDfO0uly5TEvh9I6S6UrAi6XBknDSluUxxSM8qwu7lUdoyAW37K@Ulxdyq@PP9vYK4BW/HEFP/V6vVQsZVZAEq1sbTUaDfL9uERx6v1xt0Hmc6q5ur6x3sihuvF@3F0BYvXN1dSKNKDdPJsF1sEFUQ8ntJbAs2f4rIVr175p24GdyCvXsztXVscE7EfPd3b3TrPFbUBZ3N/ZzRZPXj1J6fi6Hr1T8Cq@H@/tPD18BRGOnu/tnOx9fvB679UR@PvQqQGz4NM/MsyR2TSvRqMrfG@a9Nm1fOP9e2MwaELdGoy7P/zyJz/88r/74Vc//eFXP/nhVz//9fc//wl8/wK@P@XPn/7rrXX8/fX3/@x//uHPfgWefwXf/wDff//r7//Fj/mX3v8avv9HzO@vxTcGx7/ASsD2R7/@/md//uvv/8kv4PsvxfcX098f/uTf8v//U/yh81c//Mlf4494@clPAeHf/eUv8f9nf/l3/@GX@P@//E9/95f//O/@6F@R40@54//@l/@a//7t7/3kb/@bP/7b3/t@we9Pbv39/h7@3/8D@NyfzvvguU@@PtXn@9@Knt@FG1EqVKl@/oc//Ivfh9r6J/ztH8Mb/IdBfxC@hCEZGn7lMpHnHzD2MQ8KTuHxxxAUUP6P6Ave7GMSG/kWAt9ff//Hf47eCdjfj2Mo6LOwywgcpvYHAPtnIWFx2D/44Zc//uHP/9sffvmnP/zyj1CI5da2sjvZnH7HCAYA1@8Bh4Ab94EDQOhctrfZEluSiuBY2saJBUnPvHsHLF0CFyjKK9L6KrxJeo3cOrohIow7VvjIN4PjefiOpbUteAMHeI3JAUEZCHqSYdVqNSONqxBGoPCKccasVsIxKur2VcCLkXicbLMEeiMbPyEsELOaOWbNleqYR8ygR40wMCQIvY5lvShnStWnkGB1/JQhLkSekd7B8121VqqOa4juOyIBcGSeQJIAVUXqxrXv4L1KOAFeGj/9DkgpVTOZWgl8qpRVSi3bpDT1dcoc5T3DKN/ozxjOdD16zNhnsl6S@RgLWMkENP5mIuhHNNPwCMLPMisiO/QfOOm7gvGhnMbEH@7Hwx@hN8UXAIA3l8M9S/DN5ZCaxxA85qgylCw8MhwDcC4jpmRCD@pZM1KGyjdDL5A@0HC/z3Yt9oLoMDvLy8vg2q7Jq/IhKOvMuyj7Q8PD6X/SWspM3tiS0Ru3i5jLR6TOrzxdgV8d/veWaBsnZ8eKtJzG7jvNgjRymVV3zU0R9UHWKC8rRHmG4KRU5M9VSFrDAd1vjamSQsaOVRoTmgPQWqQX/vkTd8yUQlaWs/rGFp8KFUPGr91yufqdvrYpwZPeR2hnWVj8hWLAu3c0bF3I0Np1bptaGjhBxdiQajWxDsV0qXaydwoRTg@ZXixoDNTA67XN4tr62npxdWNjfbOor21srW2sl1ZBQm0U1otFfWttbau0tXkDBD2Gdp4tr7TWt2v/aObzX/2jeZ/5vviRal@xscaOjn6Uu5Fq41wuXySSq/r6ZmVSBULIS6qR9sR10Ml1zvcZFo90RtuYrnF3DZAmXeewqj6AD5MeSOwBeMEHMOMsPBNLwweHFbFGhlbs@TqZrK9DZVClM6gMHJs0iH8kLLiHIG0e6ty5vhE5C@iUTvEEx0tIAMrBYc9xg@HQZacu38j2xGwvgNjt8Rubdj0X9M3fHuaJ4VzwoKcWWodrD8OgZwaaf/H71rC3AOLVoI/H3UzvHwzDXr8FBOJEIQd4Aj@e7brzADbZq6MFuXwRnvTCJTc66gXgxwefPzuNPU/3dnafSRvsyeHLp1OPdQG0zp7v7Z@Gr5s8NIi6HqL4eu/58@lX8cAxwxJb38xmQfDBDz6z9KGntvw2ANG1xT2iqRWyerY5Ma9zuZuWiba9T7j18iGuoHep4tuur6fT52YfOjJoqjrUZtzMeu7aMEpaLuwWcHEg/xFHOU2zuD5hyyD32vYWjBjZ9nptIyWvy6VqsbRRgDFgNUMm1ruOwtRKagOHhPWtRnXMVlmp3hikfOkFbtfa0vlRAsuXnsHYpI/mpfH48lDyzA6MU64cOiXRwqtcRgO20BMe6IVOzzrvgQC8ckMAH@pzyzAYfD/1AzjM@Gd4u8eQp0F@MyH2LLh0Fc7qhNM1LJy3EWLhDe7jpTM8weIwdTJ@WTpFcUw3/DA8hNVCo/h0mBT6eX46lEzYmyCctyQJF8SsLitIGk1zFbdK66Wt1WIpW9oqra3DkHE9qxez@mZpcwtqS0Ev6Rul9S09W1rbWl0D0Qyh61ubUgrEl9XN56Hn0WWZnpbTRmOV22j109V6NSkFJY@NiY3xTrSUEXqMSkxeLZ0VGESUJdzPujKuynhnYAFv5NNlSTZYm6X293cL@/uy/ARfcE5vtyDLHXxZLxUKm09k2aSQXeg@ihCph297G6jByrKFL7s7@/uI4T2@FEuIQ5YveAh/sYOXTQBz8GV1lVRgWf42RFcA5C6nqESxhvylUHiyK8sjTh4e1AO4Hf62RsTu4QsGYKR9HrILYbL8eRCpAGyQjzmcSOpZkN@dHVk@4C87O4jiC8r8Os/Ul/iyQx@I5MEb1HxZPgfHuQdDeVlugRPrvyy3wdWeGODXBxcev3OGhixPeD4wJ7I8JmijfSGDZif8IR2g59kzozfsmOf8M/H4sw1BBxBkjUd7@63PP2@dn7e8yc7e58cU9MUXz4z3k5HXOm@JiK0mfFyMBUEX/cn0x8SgZtOw5wd9CUHOVFBz0jSJwqbxLVAmPueYUL/5BQZ9AUHzVoAEQvj0AbiFnyd9eD4xWjwo@FAQPcetllzBKotNp6tQxTWy9Ggx9RplomI8AlV9TS6jdHW7oGCNSmpu/dGoJG9syuUVeMqP5FVwjpVCusCYnD6TZRWk4iN5c10upx89yqUf6o@YvLkll@XNTVmt3KBgVtTrrjLOjqsF8Mjnt7EdY8uDJ@gsQuE4NcdD7ZmJuy/audybxGd7@w3A4UlzPBD3ctRnT9gViQ7cHh/sJm5Wn4CcKFQcPIps4uvyODWWah1jaMDQ48n1qFwWsDeV82odEXzEn@2c/Kb2Rm6weLrrmwWg6pXTLm5ub9c/NkDvquqVSQq6kmKpMk7RCYjNtYoCar5a9c1vufb10cY5sqVmtcD1sGV/1K8Xljb07HWuySe3bmzDHy7rm8VyfbRcz@mNpaXCx/Nt@Zua3EAaUEejv/hsHki1CvgFfONyMNW13kE4K@f4fQl6aUPVcGd30@02ySY6excTdxhxUBWlKzMFLzTh20iUdHqzmE6r6QoAL4G3KDaqFkG5yiBSoVy3iqADVjxzOAKNo1C5CWgJk@H654YupW6kDprFXNuSUtfSzfXNdi3o0L9kk4mRyQWvDxk7z8BQJE@rBrjesESunFZ7zHaqO@fHOxUBurNLAwaoOmf8xFEuv/SpaxOZ7dpb/jyr4VodpCMR@Xz9Lr@dqeVrtdqZJMtySg6nlkvrMMzAsfh3KZouZrvX3ZFDJ5vLL5BhRpkrJfWG@t1Ly74ureZqtC1GgYp/k8ps53HRS6vliVvtQ1oSllKOK5w4cTmEdqCApr0u45jGZIOTrbebb0tvX7w6fHW4zx4XyqVyibOC1ugfZ7N6Wk8Dax9D92Yd70mpwUd3Xf/O@aKSKg/Sq2vp1YQudVYVB24VrAlKHafi66uNRh3GKw0V3qrV4iN9vZRZK@ubaqqGB/@Km6kaOaB95VZTDT6nraxtMhVeaIq4qKdqeeGvb@pqys@lxGz45jpoS6nSi3cfYawpLly0iuTK5wVVyzfbN/Bfu6nDcOyGRmU39I8/efi54QDwj@DhC39EnxhcHCYKb3yX2@b/2/Sze8hpljeA46l31RoU7Nvm22ZKSm2la5l8Gq/@FR8xzkHNZ8WhP9Nfwb@3kccKKGsr4Ru8bq@w9ZrOmLmSz@fP1B8VQXHZ2toobaSk30D2b9n/DKHhjrmuCSMLEHxztszteNYLA7cTOuG2OXC8GH3Aq24eB3dkBjoOQyUHt7qilhP3E4pPzIuulk36Tfw8nphCX0lCl0WXZbMu1SUUWEM65MNWUPzgaW5VupYeAK5Re0iHreCnIkkP8IQdvioBXJY99IcqnqooqNKDB0K@@EPNHzYROUYSnjm9It1IyB6j0/EZXTaFqzj8CLiBx4XcAbcPZ08Yj@TTfUBcYQuvjIgRvMK6nArIzQqjFIlyzBxP/gEHa426SMr@wfM9iAOdQJc2r4nYstfCm9woe0tdlYViEniA9xFVBacIHAEBHXjy/ljt4znzNrVLlmE6hndpExxAZZmeJUqyrCsi1vG1AdERfbcNwx9AzFNXeA7YSlMkK/Ig6KFMAAsxdyTq6aYg77ydFaWHxtVxcfE6OKSnYCjbZkU1dlCRcEFh8NuXKWK73xHXSlUjNhM2vZGFoq3w04hKCCd8IkbdSCvDbL/Ci2pQkb5U2qA/uJ5S@a7/8GH77aDeb1TUfnWIz0ymDz3QhWJxkJVhtV@F6jGoW43KsJ7JWI1qX/1SwXe8/A27K6H8@KrIG@TcqQItuKnQV7Mf6k7uO6eR3a87GSB5lF35pvoha1QLqL9kraqetbPfgibA8wFpDqsfMk7F2IYvbgRNHBSF3jZjVBJeGOVCsasf6kYDFSIbImYy@5AZoNOv25lMQ4XEbQicjVixHz40MnZtXLFzORWh3q4@2q8PwdHIVPG9rBjb40cf6iOIX1bgWYVkbBWIh3iC1zch7UBfBXjMyzQindNI@toYyOtXqyvfPFr5ZqW6tPShPs71G1nO/nIhqg1I/BiJr8SO4ior36hsiiW0SKzIn1nlz7QVPE9pZTLA5OwgFpNTuPINhAwymYDqG5SXp/FxJNYwcXaPn5Skaxto/ZY0IhpB8punUFzs@G3LEuDckMLAQrMAeMlslq5sMwgCw8Ql1Rh4Nn70SAqSFie2IGUULjBiNXDgTleVenQQAG8X5RZF7pKv88RwIHPDASddHwZD29WNWHMl0UQNzvfadQRBMXBduKlwicXP6YGwIekBMCQ9EC6HUgSZJOSEgKyKQCitoIAgFsqJLjdSRnaaUD7hfXthywcRwsmAxjyHDCv7vkqyCeqTBS5mbVN64ICmIj2ATCANmAerwWogyNjDh0y8boN@XdzEvgDBEO59RkegGUoh8XtQCjiQyvdQR1EeUiJA2wMMwRPYiYTWfreEhFEFBSJk3me5bQWNbCsoI8fntkiQbyonA8viwYP3meqaIAj@SfWG@BB285uU6O7LbPfwxdGr073jFzsn8AvDtVL8VsbgwuSZ61IHeA1qy3LoLGXbONbNr79oM6bgUATvYMD70Dvsi1fPWbH48mkWjSMD61N83hw61HKIyfTphhpfc73z/JV1YeX3ElZM8epqOrbpl@mmYrHx0SQ7B3QFemghJTKQ4uMkGnTmwqpr4oBK3/R9cQtsDlrXyAOlmMzqka2YPpo8gVYobo2lIyOJ0@@4ZQB7deZ61rlF16T3OIJEfLr@bcijU/uQ8LZXGjpCjZa2SoVCmRWy6NADRzFwrAaOtcCxHjg2Asdm4CgFji3h0APMOscM48vV1Y3IuRk5S5FzK3SuFSJnhGGtGDlXI@da5FyPnFFqa2FqGyXCy1IBN6npmh6G6WulIIxG5UPyXAc0@rTnGhBanIGE6GsznpBeKem5uVUQCR3kDxGoWNyI3kH6BLBVhVOV5XRkecr8TXhCXyXxYRtV2D3PA6m0N8brraHSqWWGRg4kCXeytG3TAGXAHIKWUt2H@m@qZeqDht6kHFl4QAxVPXyH6Hg5IMTR6YZ2Xn3mBBfnBXNsxbnYxLmwkDExWxeCSE5lOdHTcoxrCb841iUUsMjRBRBFDoFlkDSNEaR56o3mJrl6e5IJhHOTnCGK412fFwt5oxDyahCV@n/CVg3S43qKSaUNagDGhEKnOjBVoGgaq3qtl@Vff/@L/5X9@vuf/Yr98Ge/@n/@/f@A7n@LP/8ObUAUQ4Cf/ozR9gP4@eeMNhfQFokoEsGvluUffvFLeP3v/xX74Sc/40F//Odydi1EBCHoFcX8@T/Gn9/Hn/9dzq6HgD//Qw6IUeTsjZRQrRSA@ulfMQapIZYQ2S/@gjE5AwqGImpenbfxRswMDkcQsqFOrsZ0OP/FW42BxwU1IwNe8aZHbxksADWG3DPQVlzU9kCd4TN/KKXbRruHpiWEl@uj/tNGFcb1tXOob1cdUHrE9EIacv97rMzSGYTBaRK0BFblMlzkX@RbjkIRNiPngTq82FOgojufQ0pgeBucvASnhsMWGpHqvI4I/r40oZsIOhA5qFl0h60k0gpi49xKii990KXGwVAXKy12Q9ySFi00ScL8gB5LMCFupooNUpn2gSFjZBQnHpU8zP4AjbpUI34jY/GFuJCdRheVnGg2e4f7Uw0GPy1QMS/iEilMqMpk@Q5Y5LSAV1HjWk3Cc3oFQL1QXm0kzOvMA5a/@uorWYr5FbAOeR2FMMQyxUVGGKQng4qxoGIsyOoKnCRr1ovFKRqo40C5mLQtxaPFRFQyWlS5sOUE5YBkwFgQrwKX5WzXHvm96ixqkshJYTeLPIZSb1RFOzlzSObUmKzORACcyTjV6bKcj7owAzNbUPNjIrcTPonSWowpESfWKIh70jSXwpLTt@aVXDLBW1Drjcw9EyoWfseEcvdMaGP97oSmixXjJtAv5u/dYicQE6GEj5Dxhp9KdFDYNf4Cql4kjpBij5yKCkOeHTHkaV25TAmGH@fWsDdq0TAG/PPBrQj5lu228n0c5Xh4A0p4VwIOYtBaEp8eeDxwYcjhohYcDJUMh70S4Mlz8XSd9rnjeqYft1skbth20mhOqu2eO9CrZfF2BuvCFPesm8IWcrJfCXs2oYWiDWwY@iBqzijUPJtNy7GGzSYon3ZXjRiIr1obj4SnpTZEBFcsvhKqtocDxcXbZYbq3ThJ3@XRTq32hXI4EIFpSGSHwYCubdow@GI9vJQ@uGEcs8ivqQeNtDVUyBJ0z@2756bjoiUtjD2F/iDCjQQZgwHRkmVGlrVjFIlBtNLOGqqI@uUnR2VfFhVDDeMXkwgSzMgyb5rHyFlvTnLNhcnxaEF6J59O70mc3pPb6e1anj@cppk8cbYHn5@W9KoSYQDAiIzVu8nICsOVM@QkSAm9fdSLKMK9SezQ3qUOUroDoDsCXOtC/ciGbz4d/haEv17E/9sLMIi@d9/iI2X2ZALypr@Huh8N0fxgjVoB8ANVDbc2xpMLq/bTe6YlBjo0wssymQSXg5YFoGEOBqYTXSAfIL6jzuP@opl6T5uOqjxwDk3eZZZdFBcX0dNmx7SNidlRBGQ2hjfI8bFpdEhe3S/jKOhI6MEYgCYyC1k9oYoh0zlQeUGVMbKXqrq4WnEQK6w9tBhHFB4s5h9N3E2LZpwErfI1ENcDCZoii7BkwHcwGUy4USybTOUFcpT3P7wkX7rCFt@tDAE@iIX@bJSsepv4PFbCLN2jRwhhtWSWyfZC0G25oI3PlOGnsejunNIsQxipGpRyQjtZVOLWbSUeqxVBneRayf2q5F2V7t51LlbVOLJIhO1@Whcyg3nXsO12W4lj5D63lpjrzMgE9MMSc50FvUpzjkANY5KkG@KVuVWuX6iSBc4DeF7C8zU8ESGMQZu8QgV5Q702mPKikL4xiGktwqfeRl00xkU1vo4Yg5ICN07k3oRpthem2Z5Js51IM2wBySRjQFI7kaQoBSye24rANrvDBdIZg3DkDo/bxDZ8HNfwcO31Om2ly1aWpS/TZRDIaTNd3lNAKKc76fJTcvjp8gk5LtLlL8ERta30x3Q5aBYI4MErOR6jvxDh@N5Ol3cV9UYaojnsIF0tXQ7LFGAe8VfiyA2fXm2JVX83nFU1zSxXKrMMa4wPDxezVW9k6VuAf273lttnh8ClKiuuEDAOQBKdRqzH4OlAtxHY2JrTksvB1JSY34jmUCA8U41NqmAtGZE8SqfSSWHECcNQmnyEJxCIcrM8nyKmz4zM7iJHpI4GwrCQk@kT9zTSBzoKhdcBOD6JY0fxg/JKouAFeD86MfIiOmfICZIjinAzgDqHLGTqu/QtmcKynrLYzUs/XkKzcwRYiLkAhJcSoY3JdNDhUDelxAbuIFlJKBRX@6x4HPyIRom1dyoaSQXRMhcEk7fIGQqGeONXb8tOLB6SlhBBGFgvNHgrC/sFksUYFMm6mKbKGx@QEJM50MLN9oWJ1fapcBIcFzdZ6isWdUNBXJ4kSa6kmITIGp7AHhlDnnq0LoPnsj9t@BrEHOO1MwoiiMUMU@Hy1f0E/d3l@nugUAdMmEpgnmI9vyudVa9v7WWnKLejZGcLEAOz7Kk6VzkKU4hYDqODmGZ@W12bUfFHTqDk80RD7FPafsC2cExwB9@mxxYcF2oJ3mXS8wInZi@Kixk1q5HYl1qgtGiYksDDMx5SGmXtdlp5xucVMYZgHw2PTy5gL1nA8cJDfJQBb4rlvJXj6SxapwjbNhlHi1Yu@KqDi7vEQmPzMU8Q97R/LdyiBR6HzeOnhy@ffw2d7ubmpjq7FIGtFuJG/bh06zJBOGwpZtFqKh6vo70TPdcbLp058uyWMvIAZcCgdRte/UQbV4Usi8nzqbYL8ThsjKMC10XUDIyEVEJVx8Au2xJ85bd2KiuGQBKot8DvLI3WcNUIawcu6DSb1H01aYN3syl6MSyacBnpNykmTOpJqeQeJtKz/BmLfTjsH/XphFMw7SZs8fHdJ2gf62AYxA5jjZyhFWxxwFkhOj4ZrOArqzrOSRx0Qx@iA7diKMU1HLgW11V8UCyExulO2lAp0lni6g3aFvUHrkMG28kkKSnreI2OH0y4Etkj58qgzR88FbK@EaOIb8MKVsNch98p4/O4eG6TJo4D3mSZea7ROk9xCwYaF9aAm9ION3z4KkUigmlnFvC4ZZt9IOkEauycOeQXFlSa3r51fg7VJy8uoOXbWk4NiJpzu7ndwIZiir02bCu8sEPsBKP7dsTsL7BTSRjB9FlxA3SorSxwNvoCY3FzDENDlwXamkVQ8N2ExyZ3lrKxuEvKRJ19rupLShNL9CPvFzy8ZPbScGL8pc/H@ES0WKKkVh9bpwTmOsJ2XhqN54X2FyVha7hKy5QablEbKHJKDgwzolMaeCaK65zO908YdjuwGKmgrdKy9MAhCYRbwVibb7IBTddB7Y3W2dRwb6rDPmOrRYkuH3JpllnYvJUe8CW@BHYIg6iYD77NT0ga@bOO/BmuKkoPUigUefXD@EHtRjddMBFVb7Yk0OF@V7GEyZtF8LIee8HWwa8LgqzjaGQDKJxDyZIiZwBtRlZljjqMPx1dLJM84CJ6FlMWV@oeCFYDlt988v5t0/McApMuXajIfRetk/K9x5VbdgPTdmDcc5jYDIxEx3d3dsWmN36jYlZ@5dM1CJQIdTgaWutFeV@ZFvg5PdjjSQ/cXM1W6PRxN9E7yR5GDslYspzbCKBuiCo6iinaM/aZX4Yv0JANUAKbaJuDQrxR76SNOIKbr8lUV6MS64cUPU4NEtj1QR51gZ9Zma4OeQgRqV@GTlKdp2sVKon4QJw/cGj7t5zTZIoqtiojpiQKXproH26YlWiXfCD3brlewcjrpcLGFm26Zk52mO3XtxrZlXZVZubQMpy@P/KuOhfnbu8SNAw2eN8atycfvmVsfY3h8ZLiQ26oQN@o4okOhW2ibUm2VaCzHYLAR2R04UxmjE76ooWFNGPhIaDKEp7zh08Wf8pyZaaWspV@UAv5zut@faNRdaqFSr/uNCpOJqMOM9VhRs8o6PFQVysgqPlcTX3YoK2U@RX2ItjviNZ5cULW7bIj12n33LTP6Mrv@EIgnbYKGlDfGMTb0yUMVVwv7tPF@mT0Ew1x1osuyZyKabkB3HAyMFGMhltFbRfqL/48GG2sVWbDMYcPHuC@5opQaOMZuJYGo5ZttUE8ET9RL8E9juWy2KnfZlhvQXahn8U9OS3QgSkYXAlC2@5gIiJbHKQZ5GU7hrKmYNenZu8DGUC1oE428aoID8A4CGdvApwBaurBVE4Vup@bTtg74eEKtYJbz9lSEBYcw0B4rDd0GKIJOiMdnYDHNhOgtDGZqWIbMPnWLdyJQPpdLc2DHrwf9QekHmicXsERvBWuOTAsL4yp@SO8/VJhOjLDCojGEkDHDZ6VuwRtNF40QVngbAStiGN@EN8RWfsGgtsG3p4MshFXhBBfx6U4D/h9hQp0mHy2i5Mh4lI2VFHUwDg0xJYepMuMJicq4EXdTyUW@h5CMa8LgvsQ3DeGvQXBPcQ98hcFexCMtxguCLYgmG9UmR/uQjhXxBYADHHqDaprc@g2h4ZlK3yXNe7PvuECW2GZTMDYsAowXjC8PJLxmdivzpZ46fDKlqhe0D6pWnEArNKKaDz4HtUWCkWrHAqvF7E0OU/YNbszMTFjBSxuUkogdjF9dSWBn8UIgPYHopTNhgeJ89IOM5qoPxq/0gqCt0Hmf/x4G2WiIibrn94Iah8vIZwcjeWQcyvCw@9Fi8qVR/ogIs2PI/bzx6VboLlG@QgaZTESIbxtRe26a4FuCVFV1HIibxyHquxR5FP3G6wcSo@Ij7xZ3M3H4kztwWEqtcgsa0XO9v25amC9h5gG9MitSFjg4S2jMsNOP4TOJaFrAB1yc6qetRN1RrTST83s/XKTAvqoURNvKlzQtkE1rAkC55Bn8HKNywSObDld5v54l5WVRGYtQMYPOTYBwXAbaMCeLRDjQZ9oORrfKARyvlBcy9K8Pwe5idgUCKv78OnvoXEh40SXPcL7L5Iiic1hzQx4mG/kV226yU1lj0v6@Zmr851m6UdppJHN1ieqdY@glyyzAgtP01TYzd1y6LfjzHVUfAl9x1cWy4qg0IOaeJ8qeLOA0XdWsmQWig2W4DiSQJLhji6JTobO75Si9Y5m4BPMhfG2vVADQ6oqyXCkmSMMAkBRjsfKCp2rFolOcSS2OQyUm2ykheGtWrxWgMpekeLiHIdz@9R5x33D8zzEkXgIbi9EDdMLKLO6gW4LanAQT2s3sZg5k5Gf0KbPXbejBAqTUBgIQ7BtGoCy/IxRqFZx9TJKHpITSi87F1uvg363Aj5Lwov6lQrd5x7oZ0jEyjk1mwo2m5h@Y/l06RuFY28ESQVLQjiXxKUPK0/7I3SoAj2YGymQ@HhQjI4TCzlPPXFCPMi7hoPzdmQzjIbW2zL6hwWBMDUYaEeHjqkMbubMMvCD1eLI8XV86GJVLA114rDQxagdhukhNdvbMiYTGaT4TWopP/K9fMty8qZzyfDedykVTm@V8VbPXAlnb/FuTiFNaLKcJoSgmkBJYWqaY14p4V2fOPcg8YOCNIGko8kImu7CSbcOaP18G/3A9cf0O4HBQkEbDYYuhYiE6EAh@2h9jA65F2hpV4wYBDnbhCeCUXDRh/tO@LxVTucKko4GP9QYijrGJIErn8kylh8SKqb96g3J10yj3UMisO595MMpKC6qyTeSHxQ9HoBDVuCKIjhtvvV3QPN4mARpJ/6E3iH7@K6jg/vQTCTWezFOkWi@FkPwzm2s5Dgth/G3gQGc8Q9OTp/uHR9rfDaOz9/gXZsTPs2M@zboFKG4vFvMsuISAp7h5IXyADOLuHl61Qg5yV/iESYr2IRN4QrZyXmFh0R5DnI6vc1kI4RXOTixhNagxZuPvCyIrdYD0KOQd1E0JRYtF0QLgGOseHAnN4x2G3fnvjD7LlC8a9o2EM158SBiBzqRI0H6mTB9v45pNkLieXhuJjyXCNd4OCcqgtLaPS8CKseB5NR1BHfD5AgsO5NWlUGmD17SkR/N9WJ0V26D9TUYpFkRcC0sSl4rw4DtREAuFvJ2TunzkKVEnLCCh@F1Hi7qd1GUfEhlAvZxMn18SqKATNoYK/aRTNVSzbHsR3z6MQwhCcvwrAuPjuVN1Y43SjEhIsRJDsQE3sOOzbZWjbBk9EDiUJuRa9uPZU1MST1SpsngE94zDWtOG4lxidLMEOPG1JNAOhS8FENBOLGisaDl1oLIExF5EkOLUEtBslJwfDvZwCFr0028ilPoH/EnaOxJ4gK41PzAB5zyMc88XwhLMoiE7pI8n01JaYI3CHNPkalbepEo7ck0xvlC4qWLI9B2DyVFmKbJl@u67sjpLIVyIi4oAkkxw/cwRHA6AtCD6ruoCDHwRvpNfkX63OiDVmibY7aDOrVBhpOkxFoo3tLto2kvtGfJ/NFgYFvisB27otU2YVKouI4LQxHGmNKgSQe4a4fDZ9El1i4hksYOEfOVxW/DFgH@6Pyc3y7M8H4/EK14Ybk11KQdZ8IvPsazaUW@IinuS0cBbMOwL0YELzneesKbrDUpsMDDs9rl7Vtcw42rcnirMXRpZUn60chqX@x@zoqFwqZeWNVjLAumqgva6hrdnxyoSEFAsaAXCuv6miTtuoMJ32@itFXEtZZDhFn2HDv611A38apxx5R2oMcgQB9vRje9S7OjSdKx2aE54NaIOIJVmS4Pd4LD9@gDuhUaIcLrv/0sv@Mbahg@sX/mBgXatNs5K@ES78D0@taQLwS7lxbeSh4ua3dd23avaCIaV5Q5PzBS3xwCU1ZUliSJjAUIWkh3oTP8wA1D3IJstNxLMu4h2AB6qoU2kWh9VsKTrXTDfSwxfo1qjBJIr20bVh@r0xwC8OhLxIGAAMhaZ9Q2b6VBIiI@kYbgeueO2x6huQQjKJk8SD@X2go0d9OzQPpGDKZSoWgx2qGAT58dnLCTw/3TNzvHewzcR8eHrw@e7j1lT75mp8/22O7h0ddk8JU9O3wO0uWE7bx8Cr4vT48Pnrw6PQQPeecEYsoUIO28/JrtfXV0vHdywg6P2cGLo@cHgA3QH@@8PD3YO8myg5e7z19BZ/15lgEG9vLwlD0/eHFwCmCnh1lKNYgmRfHY4T57sXe8@wxed54cPD84/ZpS3D84fYmJ7UNqO@xo5/j0YPfV851jdvTq@OjwZI9hxqSnBye7z3cOXuw91SB9SJPtvd57ecpOnu08fz6V0cM3L/eOkfhELp/sAZU7T57vUUqUz6cHx3u7p5ihyLULzAMCn2fZydHe7gE69r7ag@zsHH@dFUhP9n70CoAgkD3debHzOWROUu7gCpTL7qvjvRdINHDi5NWTk9OD01ene@zzw8OnxOuTvePXB7t7JxUmPT88IYa9OtnLMrztg5IGHMAtCAf3k1cnB8S3g5en0Ge8Ojo9OHypQiG/AcYAlTsQ9Skx@PAlzy0w6fD4a8SKfKACyLI3z/bA/xh5StzaQS6cANd2T@NgkCAw8TSeTfZy7/PnB5/vvdzdw@BDRPPm4GRPhQI7OEEAwInpvtmBRF9RrrGcgC7uhMoqBTU3S8XJDvbZztPXB0i5gIYacHIgaguxbfeZ4LmGJmTnLrnduoA3u8onpkJut9yze/h0DzQ@bpVPjvxfQadTSi7eJcKgowkD4VWsglJf1eyYrdF503K6Lg7Nw2h8Bbvvn2fRvLzKFLzd5ZYbBsRCOUVIpZrN1ztNGOeeNJtq9j4xE2TcFUMcjb8NShV5tF2jQ8P8xNxSnFG1h8IAT5Zbw4jPtTwMJx9Uls93TBENN5Ig4mCaSFiKAmQdlIy0w8RwWCxJWmJOzhWRGbPpyaJgedP14cf5GL3wviHmAcKZ71vI53EMS2SgOToW0g@JkKU2Ya6N9gFYXUpS803z4lwpxJPDIb@YoFKDOAQ7hGHguaLeEb1lnk9Fz03HJ2JxBxApK4GNnsB2Dr@YGd8Ey5goF82jnCl8ao8eakANJQRKocqTou1FYveJ8pBHx0PffK5QrYT2XchG24udrw7e4GCuUFyrTPk/C/1528KtgGhwEPq7OsVr0ONZgwNAA7Nw@AUssSZ8STWfj8UBrYz0yRAYDQj1EOjK6kCfil11z6RuHc0WcRsO8fjQGXvWOE49iOHPj3dePHm1vw@SE6ldK61vblQkYQbJG36V5c@vMR2ybYvcBS36ygI1jYJirWQX9J79GQuGMZOLWHoIiObDg0IjT7yYOjzOzHUEbvSMTwNhdn00@@Sg5TMZLTd5Mr9dfkkK6uvclikqgJLIqoq56Rtj0vANUJWoDrT50WV7QqU2xh/EHTb/oImHGRIVSFQxsz8YTqDmwuCC5J68H@wCpbENbfFCEE0O6vHACPYgccagzKStsbhFkt5E3Y6VIui1WNDYXqnYKSYQsTRNRWA5j@xgQhJHrh@0YO5pgc9Xor6B82thsRGD0P7WzvAE2LgfxswFFhX5nLNoGAJzo1aFInr4MExpm@FEqiqI4vP/SXt@8dZApPANDWwKcbDzKORzGEKT0I/TKrvmNRVNrSCeiqix4h1q7rzsCCyVwE6NeA/M@jGOK7LyR15XYRpSAPJ1ABKyM8Gm34kfhP@/IE/m4N@GASdgj7hFcthyRuY9OUlYOa9g9EpMsa6CHWOxbWoRN@NeX0dobuIF0wszJrbhjfnCErBAlM4k8Pia23lV5jAAKznOa8TbL1pVoEbcM2Dk9Jja7gO@0u857f5ACaykBl3FDN5GlnSubLBFDl9UvoRfYLHknqPRu8d0@JZkBg64QIq1JuwzX@Y4MjrJHMx0foUmPcJWTlUT2aAHLTyqTgXRtILGPxY7jKJephOE3oAqutgCa7gcgoYeEwI/WAEJBAjtfYpnWLAN0qwhoXPzjdvvaZafiV4cr/cBEchthp/S7mnf6NKYGbsisdUZ91Rjkojns44wpNkyh1fYXdgcO23xjrAx5TPaZY6JiLnIUI0IhK@qAdepk70KqadpSqyvIfWvnAsHb84w@RRXAKElzHLGz8Vr7IVBFjrt@@VbjhLPIFtryfQPHNr23ubrlTg1RyN3SAVH@p/5EUdA47xC7RL6oYhLRvsCPeWgjlpXOWsMD0orJ3IeGJqEMQOZEZ6n9N8sHBBgXZnaA8vkMyecRCrzjqz6WaC@oIu33dD1NbrEPHMVMgXEgQ9umBVqEJKMehNu0pxtbURfeNahKKVo82kZNKerK61ljPqG0zX6lj2hXafv3Z6T952RP9AGEzS2npwNpHtBAA5oH5rsjeV03CufPYHmgBNJJy9fnRwlJ/5iM1@7fOaLsS8gDfaEUpZm0HfxIIvvdodQNGaFTcRtUV403UPzhGKmhaa1JuiBp4U8qkCQbj/UjD9/@Yp9bjqmB/rgEe25ZM@ttumA@ABlinZh@j0uaRB8H1M/EamzfdRdaGanwkyLJnXCuT1JJCCwZbFqKdAUgWBP2LrGufkJVPXYnKA2m@EoX51gUqnnDsRhDZw0RWWTT3F2R3ZWQoPabw5On@FgnA/MaW4GurVgrg/nErnq1OeTtZAZz3CGE2CKND15A2TfNXejMTqrARilxeykQV0f79/p4LSf7UNW8aovIQWoB4GmalqXaMGXpuHuU0a0z1ZMm0V8q4hDr1lxF40QHYnSk6LSy6Ihdy3L1rfYqYl1lx3ZRhtGWOxkhNFXV0EPfOL6QwR9scNYoajrek5fxSnaVyc7GjUE/AZmXSXp4MXR4fEpMFLYLQoqRthnIvPJkirfjQXsyKE9Vcj9OxTIATxIzOI7Yh6q4IFxBbnCVyzksgxl3zZwuhdy6CfVYZqSxSl51yNrrnhYB6pQojlCqv4VCl@@NEIpxbBnyZ6ssAjLu5aQTjpiSRHeIW021Csb10PfUWTyAwFgjskPYnk0MugIW0RQJn2zH1JvDYPe3eAA0rQh2pBhfC4VKkc6m0YtCbinxvF0TNwj4aNJp75/2fZAthiXUOVwC0twYgnqDMkmNcyN0bJsC9oA0NXuudjhcHEVFARNQcTN1EpU4qEBROyQiJY5JqSgdXXcfgjKqZKk8ISe8B/4k7bLUucwzMaRlj8wzQ6ZrxoNuH0mDNegldvQc/Cze@XIcJOUKtC@SQ@EDdrJA9k3svFAPx7AbPEyl4LcQK0Kznye9nBYzxFBjk6G1EjRjK4yZ4SdZbjOq1KxG1AhMK6KjFhw@hJQDLK4KAVUQXlThSAXVZcs3R5F5T19OBMjkoVIf5AMQFx8VddMBgToMe/COQPAK2k1JGDq3GdADD@zxN2JObDkC@YX953imTaF5xEyN1FDZu5baNeczw247NzFXwTWAo7xNUKT1ghnTpPiVZM64JuG1GchASq06haDLM7BmZuLc3U@zpzAKRYrD5xLOk@Hsaha8FxwEx0uyEdkRJT9z91A9NKpP9vlC0xh7s9tt4XGNEFSQGr4mGSjgo170wgsweh4KD/ZmTQCuh1kSZAuzjYFugvbhvZh1th2MGNRO3N4QYmAKm9LdHyMUd9FzYmc@CNaFDnlhEVR1DqmTIoiedwXZDeilQVK4SOXWdQycSdOHF6knIzST0TRp6II4pJRWokoRSk6Pj5VuhgDRT8@kzkL9BLalUQlwKphARWkvjHmo5sCHQakaRq04504uFhsiAqCgPU2C88XInhDiuxmJJbteRrBK23Box3f8rJMdkgLSSNU42DrHokBgkqET8g2i6OIDKmCDfQS2uRQA2JEvrYpihOTVGGGeYCUyLaHZ7WUeCpqmaUGBl81RCgfO7Z40nXiAa7Sy/C3whSRQC5OLAdCWwdCFALjyR5GHYayvFgCOViQop6Z3mICDkpQ4vKbtozxbkBREu0qkNwhTu6ckd2ACv05OkpJ4oeyfdDruC/2KDHRcIIKH9qWF0qeOYbhGa0xEwrqf8IZa@HJDU2E0kMQX49SbgS9RjIXC6Gnu5J5MLFeJeTCbcABs0M@LQRe3NsQ63AOAeUdB4@x7jlOEgvWBV1w2ucsIy3FGtJZdLdtcQmVZFtM6PK42TkCOFnkAXHZqVxJMfsyIofT3YiU6DkTlUSJveHdOewzbl2YI1KlRCzk/6ICx@2O8Ya9EE7ncKLYF9WIEFdQ7rdVixA4KPfbqgUHjhX77dUiMDAdspbiT9eLRElwFuCmRDFioDmluAwKAsZxqPEUFBE0acQNzJi2MofamFQVc53SjKoUskjYk0umQY8xLxhx/ViyOgLz6mFpNKLcQh/XvjA7oZkMkftwiFSTk10CL81p61CY6SAFKqOGiveYhBFAYvNJMDFm7vO9m2RmKM0HLDQGRVOq573k6d4E2qBXKaizCmVgUikifnsu8blZ01bREKs8e2lPuLtMUI0bnlyvg9CyNGfFV7qDqkyMqmTuYiWUZPECTLl7YcrdA1M@hkk07FXoL8mZ8tB4sHkXirOzWRz0eAsDKYEDJG3HwklsHAdfGZO7cC6BspWiPXUG31UWRoj05LtwPJrGQcbae@FqnPDsGTjr9sH03GlTaQs5m6wrcygKqUrNkpVFskhq03hXwAWqEo1ttYtWzwpHAqm7S5rblBCRcStxL1wESiVNHYXIovavL@BfNlasyfbACU9Mw4C2LH1ic9CQEXyGiR8VCyPEBFlyHCoCkoy4PXRa@NFoddrSBFqhXxhNvTMnj/mET2zSSYescYmVqHHBEC4STkFvFci3ecOzO9NPzU1/4A5Ax@nOJYDg@ziPzyelpkR6pJpODa3v1ZfN7c9m8xXX26YMxt2/kT@cyXoRso4H06FRO@aV6P1vwyzyEpTAb6HJ14M6soDIz@YSiQvthpjcYs6o3zI96T5NncfQ8MHHSItrriSlUmynDUNmYbiIro0im8qmSBLVYKwIPhsNcL3G55s7sXHjHJnJK/A0LF7pTtCajEnQHG3fNBxhyUh0mOcerl@EsFm0qY6HuygFy2kDo30zNv35jl8U0jFFCO5IvoWtlfllj7WarpznVGSjlARZXNdUJskxLfddoOCEWg1BlacVlaDu4GLoCtfMhb4Eirk6fwrsPtrTbQoRVOJFSYoB7xTq2@toeTEzR4OQlWHR3IOV89StcJb7HurW5L7q1n8BTk4XqBRzC@1BdLDlO4Xa9CCfbskNrGX355hueX26v58weNKaBKOCvumtFwoFNIIzcyUeLlDgKrHl5pPQeZwTzw@uvvBet/IYNXkJ3tw78JAGAEVoXJrAeoJLEyPob2JWuXA@x8FTOe99Dskt8HQYbeO0ws3tr0@p8hFKZJ5ZZu8wg5i/dyy4cxoURz5kEFiC/WYQG9XQSznYJgfsQY8uWtQJt6QRMho3i1MLuPBRrV1LD8S9kDTPh3f4qNfRMUT5mWnbbpa9cT27syTz06HJCPv78QgFDoJbCXnj8elOiSwzLy07dq8GgsTuO@cXM@Glu3z2k84yeeYAV9IU7MeOzfO98UCR629lqJiQ5QxmM8PkBh7vOZehi/p/23vT5TaaLTHwN/EUJVASAWIHF5GEwE8gCS4SRVJcRFEUL4SlQBYJoEoogAQk8ca0x/bMxExMhN3t9rjHdscs7Zmw/9oOLxHzCLffwX4Bv8Gds2RmZRUKJKVPd@v4dO9HVGVlnsw8mXnynMyzROkK/X6w7MYMmv2g3O2qE6sTnoKZYQ8UtlTeE7RoBiNvsnYwnqesQpdRmSPmyxJnvzCMs/tzI1LDm5u@tK1ODLqOnyNoLkem3zS81JMx2RVyox8GuSbiMMswRJvQb@LDStwW0OnU9//D0208OUDjRjrjVSaxmr8xvR/yMB5XlnHdazZhefFJ/LJ0NSbBEalM5UhLAVEjBrZrfuoDPxObarrC7R2q2hwMO3VfQ07zZ0lDOMcr/Lw@RuQKFMsP8IlqE69SsKzX@xRcxaNndAyHChSjdAcLVLBAJPKkXvx0EyuVSsZjJ5EwSqUVeEiljNJKyVjDhJUVYw3eV/D9aTE/N1dgzbm1@BdIXJGJt8YKwKAtCAO5rcErfKP4TChK4RA/zhQfJwuPK8XnywU3c1paOctkzuHpv/7ZP/yvf@/PMyXx8tf4skIvp79SmdLpdOZx/cvjp7cFfD9dO5t6XDt97JxNnRdwliG5P@q61VZVMxNL139IMF1pOV@PG8DRxovFKWPq61d@@tDzHrveI0Y@8IpXW85FlYobBGG5OFWaevoUnp4Xp95PxdFzh0ivqvTPkG7EkZbTfTGhlq6PSwerW1t6cCEVtLSJnCZeuFeFcprVcS3o1MdJeXueOjXSaeMsZXxUzUOF7gpn9DfRmEKNUW7Mr0UjZe9I@560VKliVj8lBSPWe2JttLZ7TupFUkGJvpEyGBZ60lhi1TmCkQCCh/kLbJQa4@WG3Yfmoq5bMXWam587S01OTlLNpJ1bqROZo9ocL75xXVOWJU039qjnwJKBviM0bPKpAQARGZOTT@rQjqd14cehQwElscPkr3BqckpzjWFAk0wORTih4vcaxG0IyzLcYal1sJn3ydwaeYPhQxX3oAEqbLrxxaCQvlGOVDvUIghq0YPR40kwtLxy0OkFl6fY8hJgPeCJIQiQkQfSPc2gouijfAd2Y3RSfRQhfoxZebMkLO7t1vC8hRE3yWjCvQHqBJiPi8FqdaRXRKyBS9bMJl588ormAfOM9ogxNNEWtlPH2wV0QtpCz7vM8MlYy8BBwnpADkf44WiizXes1WFTAbsJj7Dho0NEjilN0zBBzp14QuGlGrmI4fKSDkw7wLs6nBOxCu@emi1ND1TyFgoaE6MKl05clKQLPTHTnFPU6MudyQgAcbGSorRWlMoOcJVtFEHxUASQgjnT5LAWSMPQ@NjqfAyLNU1ailQlV5NnTWSgWKoaS1y8UnVs9BuNc2/QvW2n2hPodWzXtYSiihgm0sJhK@EuQP0wFeHKxGzRo3FPO2pF6f2TU8kcwDzHczD2OQK1QyfFLPBlROVN1DxkvbhJnz4uhWRHklsze1adTaW49keSFjvkDgRT2W/K2IpAeGB1UDnAVMMHQ1ihCk1QGmoPDuEJrZJx/V8o1rtKOJMqRtxe6bXFOVWTQ43OBw9JHkQ1EwiAHymijXQ4JTA44ZuYLfPc6vnKJNnoWtiXci9uJepxkX8kjUcNuwHMom6QDIetSMJHgW@phI2EV34DQrvA2tXhc092Bnc11sVSJblL5DhjYXR@KHokm6O3GlYwoA@Xb9I/QrS54l5nuTyPeUy8qWp4o3BnDQRcNJHpxTRZ8hMAQS2COEmdYlDgADaAnAaWgUeFsz7w2gTGya3v5ESjAujl4WKWYIR4y/kiW3obEuT@d1mvbyhrXXQ1C4sPcuE8gD3aUyavQY5O3eNuFMjQFXhjSkYdya9F9kvdfgs4f1ZSFzuKHkfeq1S1I1CV7LoY4RRxSo50WHY6pY9loKjsr1f6zF86NcW@G75IDw4xjdNx4sKxg/g6wZs57KYSLrtmiGXl6630ISFcMCjNdDk6AuW0vVabiB7UdUdq7g3ObdjUkDK8pPKyz4KzQNUYHTjBIt9DIp@u7x@CpFs6win1e/ZW78fz9HR2R62xmiqRYtUDX1AFNliwCNV4RjzB4ynFvf5BYgHSAQsIAVuqVF0TniMR5jyEhBl97Z6v2INYNvkh@iGazM0vxqMkJys@bLLugmQ0WTdRo7qLUoIpZE/YiYWG3LXJJLxbsxoN4DhExAUoKmpTnyoC7CmekH9R5M5N0VYbJSJuRjVa7qZgEClB4JqenW71vF2lxx37sFsdbsEmRK@7HR7PA4S3D5sRRl6lL/u8RksNYDWitygne3PiQV2kI/MqcD71HrEGPZNdJSh2IQQB5ggCuE7Vf9ffWQ0Nev/57EJxz7RvwqB@ZA7FZd3wj@wT8COJAGieAHJahdNgbgoRxiV/dvxIn1ggCDKQ@EFa8mipXIJZ/ZaxjGV8Lv08j2o08WJUG5dKGi2YoFkpct3dFZstHz@q1rsfhWDTq19U2v1WzxI9G@mW7BcWShqMij6GJRHdRC@C6A3PKqIB1HP6SO6VJY@OR4ZB3Gn9QLinFqxST5YhQuVhQQhhEoomP0p0U//p2NFjGoSowh7c87M0P7K3hTvGhrn7ZSlqoIN1dOKmDQf1F3GuiRvscVDts4bq9SOf8IHtAKRgM6YdpMlMmm/1McYRRhfwREzU4P4@ZPY/ZSGXUxBlFQ9LUi4VatRMwzxZn@yHk0Y2RbcFulQLM4UKu3ZbalsKcUITXrXY0LCC0IL8Dy2w3iO5@bg/DVXSPlPnXR75FpqPOZSGcRo6FRNDO7M@CtRXnRnROQkiOY7wgMZ4jmpOK3GvDyEbLJRATm5zkMmWHJPqaQh5AxAjm2dSsREjn@KSe1McEGWFOdWQRFXsbt7GJi6D8VTP28FkW/08pc6yG94G6vGsIUK4mgb3IsocRVTu@xDF7QrDE3/5YWjyI8CPpdtIJGz6KtIhDEb1ta58BYzQJULcI8UIB2CEMLp0r6k1LAgOBlBy9ouSGZ42SudAFv28MGsNVL00lnpYgHQDvqHUQRyb1PS75hJwxMBdReA/YHmRSpF9nO8EBFjWTERlIk8QiA3CtzqNEL7JjMxkPCJuZjOsShTLPcvFqZIH1BTxxc34ZvaeySBexTRH3FzghkIsx7RREa5C7t/9aK8bcyzt61/okTRQZO9QmsnztOOgye59p9SZSRlhywDwRtz4zgNqOivJ8x6E5zyZycgENIE5DVTYgsqodEIc8LomdMORJjN8nOs5/mD5UB50/zGdf0scu@SSX80AxSBkJXeA/BlCFQMsOARSJaQFOvXEnQJUK4P50Fo8Vo3YRUKtbybLHTwnturQAyE1KrRLu/JMkVht7VQx9NRUnhAZk6HFjBjb91ZbdHVk1vEgXJ1SuXHtPFgcO2SmpLdobBa7RFEgfeRK787Tp4ZoGx1ZB3iMUEHfhyhuhw8ZHzpMnINTF4gQJhLixZYCy0RxfU7o@QNnEDm81fk0nBFB8urxId4JTcbDe7@jMB@OHSp6F36wQ@d2wJUA4YTj10knj15rIt@K0CA@75mkdKD3pzNLv2kkHjpVlaP08LnIe/GzHO/F@t4zdDN42oC7D/vjZ48@5ELG23@Mad3N0gTvv3RMAX94gmLcrmpPuQsDau/2WHM07il5uL2026Ptq@BdP6Icx3tStdGA7biP1vjDHoBAQ3yKVKfhmQu5JFJ824YphXSuXpBCEDGxKUHJTJT25DKDBDNN/JX@xwhTTeGwaQLAkXoR@WzBqyu7zh7AUAkQDwdIr5Tk2hyLRSgQccFTfBWOVCaa7I@8KVYy98CYrohqRR9Ee6gTzGOtdKu9B7FY3pUcW7cbHfQGi7EGAvPQTUcw5ua3smQP4cumH8yXTU7Tmfa0x55NTzrAW8x8J4zfL5/mHdACnKhqeRQXKh3gk8gBKIYBag2T@mG@oFr6ldv3s32/sC9/rBvD9B89@zKt0F/3MzHTHhNTD2VivAyiVB0P3qicyk/kAZZthyTkacH2cH22vz5YN7I@O7Q@10QPw4aXTxS2qVpMDqm2d2OLEmqiigrp/DG0IqS1vKY/RsXa/mjERhc0j7e3Dc/8sg3/3d6GMwoXGFbgnp1GG/pfxv7vwtijo/rWQnYhW/lh974qLapPrGjgvtUwoo@M3PJPzz4M1rIfBouzu58me5PL@cxxF357k58m5xcm@REe4G1Gvl1PLk8@x2zzt5PDTLFYhEcBpbQOUJZfKpiYa/gc/izPSbjzw8nlVJGKf51cnoeHXD4PLfkwKC9@GCxk8b9o4Y@J/dBvVxTzMQ6qQ94rxYbgypBdSnC3XQ/kqrY7bOEUkOK4/4AUd34AmqIGo/LMIL@QFbwKTCD2sneNHgitZk/ZVAn@kfx89chbIVtcSC97QlePC8EKUFXE4YeqoN1esF6eZz/p1A@5BK/Rxscn6Xm8uv4onP2pBij3fsRmsio3iBcxqhgdGePvcvanqHL/txQV3gGjusa/uNsUu@LCjDoonogY0xMlY6o1M9NTRi0U1qzaOe9Xz80pXVMcMmP@1NrB7uqr8iFrF5Km8eruTho/HcD00cQBDC/LvqFoUkEuvF8/XN1DU/6jtT0qc0xWG5SKl2ZpUcvjrcaSge1K15PXRi49gw735jLZ2UxuzsgtLGWfLeXngWCaddcoDxzx9BiLGtStEW99cxMlzIPfhEu2JWNjb5tKkHXQ9MRa@fWusbuzfZKWqZzuj2mwuvu67MUoCPFft1U@QADkDL6J7jEYYYG9COMsuyFbFBoy9fzp1a5TzQA7GUiGBEyEL/70fscCKkdpQh46KKl9DMDD1tOVOyAtvYlpYLpQj@Qi6z4z5vrvPme7c4@M@uzO1DOjnt3pzDx/ZrSy4n9Ga7Y9s288evSIArBNohJoM/JQquu1aet9eSI2P2tMk5/muPdlZ3dvIivfJo73Dydy6tv@2kRevWytT8yolzK8zaq39eO1iTn1tlJ6NTHvFdtZnXim3tbKqxMLmlv9nYlFD@bO2kQuq9gFlAcnOCApB5GHTPGC7yvGk8OHQDIgIuZzaG1MT99c2KzaUBsGcjfM@3LL7P4g3WjSdop4BVI8bQNLPd0227wfREL2A2Na2w@wQxPYIcni0O7wSFjFTIy6/hR2MU@kNQx58SSAWfIf6wnE4g7NiAHH1Am7k0dBAbinnaPtba7MEUIA5WSJIBoC03bYPRr6QICu0xUJDg4PiwyErVgHUna79Y1mJDiagnGamMCYuH7sXldbSfL2ioazNwiXXL@SpFtAY6iW4GfYE0oshvIbXs3XqUGkvVneXeceAgTcOnw1xDkQL2KKPhNkvLyRbx96/teu/xVFU7pcZeDcLIbHLS1i3rhf3VfezIrAkDhjEgkKxtcqiJhoLXXXzeGthToct3IZKsqSZiK@PYe3Rb75x3IJqhF2RciCAATCCH0TtxGvaUKBdiIzjaIzhdpqSrfrQF@EvrZ5Q0I1UNZgQwOjqlahGs4JPHUrBAiy@NRs4FiTN/4KvCN5hJkMLDksk6QhP@bm8SOe4CUN5GQLkSBNrVgdmLlm16OJcirAYqTR31kT8dcplCylcwL1GOgeRRBGYvEUl2@Ob6LVmTPlAnpIuWDe4qSJISI4393l9teo2DSvF/JbQdHf7y@5tb4k5xGXJi1kni@IVnXDL7tLictephH4AphNB0Vb6@Ian4AJ3VExKbVsZX@@VErT8ri9vxPlYC8efXMvkCyP7UX5gd34eb2Abc2bItALIPExgEsuqRKyiAKRDwMBeyGBoN58HwjYQL25BGvcB@AB5WHL9cqnvr08bNJLwaUM6xavzYkqcBH/a93/2vC/4vKlOOXPQR6aNb4aNXzKzRt4cw5PC/DQYFrpL9j0v9IBf9EwZZmmosBcAzoFRCVuyibOCwLEGClI2rU6FXZlDdBK65WtnfKh/yvCS7sV0fCLnt1pUR1xfzbRIPzuxvAlrloUayISmN@M7XEdScJn5eBwv1x6jfIcOqdUKyDIA8CfoPWIN4@baPzd6YDgAxUljdhByZiOG0@xZUpPDV8eXAUfEjTG1tjoO3mqSui0q3f/SpqUekgjHE3MiMWNrx8@wJaafWbk2s7XmfZM59lMwxjOPENml@EoHkRQeUlgdnhpegHDYXpW@63eUmhll9msMdudMXrmBXDcg2x3FL7QP8Lzomn2q0E6ysK7rVswbrpVx7Nfw33Rz9rczUXyKQDMA0zFZQxpuJ2Tc74E8ec4PemrZLC4LeSY4pvach9H629LitvynCodbcNvR70WX1TdCxAwImTMbDs9DskiPu7SidoeJnWlJ2EtyGGMnQ4KB1AhfoE5GmCS2GU36PtXhAosilz@jwI9yu@bzzEw3xHqfjsYoPC3h1H8YlRjJKJa5vZMh1qlNQPwlkUFYr1CELB978Jlntbi@JLgiterHICC/536fHcwjL57kQxJBvI8mqqmacg3NW1CvnXtViusSN9pYahHM@QbxnoPSQbCMOZLFw0D3DBQHXs3rAB7yvI@nJ1qCDzVEXx2pjka8WEe1pV/xIO@iw8xVCu7C9va1aYgMJdiBmpjPbmGdv3sLDMICBhodp@Ax2cDdns9oMiaalrFvZlEYZmC4CUkAQi9UbSq7VqjagyWUAts8CSXX4gnNYAaRBheq11tjYNpaEDxcG8UyKRxQHNf2kG6CjROwSBcr3zAXSEVsJ078nv@rzAvDr7MPEHuyeUXNZlDlpwHbml04lD6KVrp@lwceZ7hxnciF9cR@nOrT31r9SmtflyT31V10Tj1t@Msob0vpaRvU@yjXODfVZFstb@2@Df1WJ81pnk1ZvrWbLulVSNiVfuqVWAEBVJzSnaFwGPCA4kEwtIBfQN9oeFjchda2tt/pikcuSzDFM9bDaRbqjWenJdXKng3UKmQK6tKBU@WKpWodO@PuyxsX/qmKxYbf0sDl1rhS65YNFWNJqOpFLmqSFmdaJIvcYpRF137VzCMdTTZAEGpGCWCVcE8F2bLKUZ3qakYR45KR8fXUdLqgA7eXwll4lq2yPsibMN9tvJ@QHV1vUv2A7pkByrrNMQ4PKS2faoN71buqgm/o6W@qGgVwzag0z7gidGxvunWu5Yj7yZuZOxk6UIdj/RFE7hel0768LZGNIl1JjFNjPWN3W1sWyRV02lf1HadRro36EXZBU4sLjwjxXU3XghgxA/mXoucoInIwzI2MwdV8vyriYalRU@1@S4ZNCiB3J7a0AZpVPOByYl7pGxvUp5NuniMGWiqR1hshxyRR/dgY4IB2LMd@Lsltwt4XjO9532go5gkSR08v4RljSWa4mGf1yo87dgpAgbTO3qmO2@32n08uIEn3pfNTlJwcl6zcMvHnnjxtMNcv2GOdOuyD/ylgBtPYPwU6NQpKqrjf4KhTrcbczHMH09fmIOGhZHMY/Fkbj7@JJeLn0VGiay4IvWxDmFAB6EQkz9gkDRGDEmzK1oDZZNRI8pMCJXNLaEBoDZ3JIlB9jmQZvOpJwKCniRVeW@/0lwqFX3iBV/cTXNjvAJ8yqRHmCLmPr6kWBBvxPRczLiFtBsDz4xtuA5BMmrxyB2S1J@MnKQPyR@pqPSHF4pGRJ/fsShzhwjzzdLKDxQLfmHof2Hov4Oh/2Hc/BiWPAhydMUH2PV72fBvZ7@CEYny38OH/SBG4Nk38QFa7KI7eIH792cV9Eff1r9zl478NnPYmD9et0ul0mE7193fKJ2XLkr7J/C@kt1OHF/OrqzdrGysNEpra@cvz1d3zDcLpdlt59W7hZON5udPJnDvm7sv339uOfWLyLt95@bY3LuZMRfcUr//aWtz2NtcOWqvHsydPLvJlltzzRXz01rLXXt9@O7V4cbcQeLm08u9l5/b2ba718xWF9szm6/n364OjzuRuWvrqLG@be22Dxrlo3x7e806WU@sZrcPFt/kstvlm/czqzeJuWxmy3m1u7F/dFkrv2/tb22fNFY/2dX5T1c3zlamsdhcvdx/G9mdeZPb/LS7e17OL25sZm7Wmk4jm99sdecu3@3vrRydbF68qpbb63NHi@8uh3vzF2/eXPd2Euezx/P91@5solN68yb/qrNxfV3ej9Sq9mF3xjy23@Scm5s9e7H9zHy1s3neftPNdTK7c28TB@3Dm7XySuvTs8HM0cnxm5vZg5P@6zcv3@9mrYODWrk679Qa@YPLw9lIvT2zlbg@Kh8tVDcax2/a11ubcydrmdcX5k6psde62jjffG8f7G1vlWbcfie3vXrdOtm4uHx9tba61bL3rlqd0mxmrnXYONndjRy9tGpr5uY792Xp8uIkM7dyNXuSaDgbh5efL65erhwc7S7kB3vDrL3q7tc2m4O1/fn8Qqbe@rT/uWm/zh29ScxfX77MWyelz73IzOfh3OJ268Rsd14m6ufvB59amcRRLrf6fuvzycnB5nW3VuocfXq7vn/Zfd3o7Lq72f2Xr17XWlcLvUvnfefgIFfPbphXrxPZamRwtOnCGJmH1blnh@3tN85gzf60v/Xenf@cuD6@mjHXrvbflj7tZ2s3Heddp7tttVezjd1q6a3dK/cHG/XF66Orzdb2p133JPK6nJubW7eb7krz7eziu8xGonm18W4ldzDI7nT2m7Pz3Z23b44tq3zx7ujzfn1u/a2z0O51zt98PmqXE@XtwcVncyFbax2cXHUiR3MH@3v5m84rq91b39x/Pd/bzW6/3WtsDnOlN2bupvNsdTi3NujOzxyvveueXG12nMyJ9am/lzWvE40Tpzf7xqo162@tevtV5ODlxdHO3tubrbn57ka7Y63sLWR3tjdXd84bs6@GW6/75e3aZWNj6535zjmcv8qXV47n194dzPQOr171FuvX7Zm9hcRhq907P0pEXvYv@s/2jruf3g7ez5baNXNmv3ViD5/l2qsvnfzgbam8@/n8as@xd3Lr@WHmaNu@amU/H9583nTnS8PEwuCo17Z7h7nBXO5NZObms9N76bx8c7C78nL3/cvqrGUdVy8P3jayM0cLGeuiO7M1P7@RK68325/ai2bu89rrmepM@yLhbl9lGquNo7fHV63L9qv2ZT2ysOjWV7be96t2uZbPZU9WmuU5c3tl@zBnHp2/Ophd28nuvWvsHX0aHDZW3/WP3u5a2fLly8Xt89l3@28XXz17f@geVo/td6@6O5HBwozt5uYX525mDhYXdi@6BzPHl4u9968u51dax7Xcy61821y3uu8WhgtXzueLm/ObAzNbO99Y@1Tdb5aBkh7tZatz/audwUFk5u1h@/qZs5I4uaq/etfJtRaOrWeZw0@Xi1cXF69u1uqzx6XPn6pzG5fm4sF6ptZan9tI7K@@2bs8Xzv@vDDbyK5sv62@G5QveieRN5vW2uXi8dXuYJh7s34wbJeyndbc9cHx3PWhvXJwvHmwcPG61m3WNi8vgDa0h0eXN/3rTfPZxeBm4dXF5dtqdvvdwmrHnd3LRl6aW@3G/uGrd6VEM28u9q53T3ac44XjwdzrBft40d5dsF6VmhuDN7vNcvaZYx0fDo7KF5mVVau9ADRlr3XUXd19s/n@@KWTjeQ78yufV@25Z58S14OT@ePMXmK7f1I/zLePu93Nd1Z3/d313rtXB6WtxFZtuLF3Vd09Kc8d7Kyuui8T69a8OdycuXFLqzOtph1x2yuDnUHXWZx5f7V9DjuB3VhsbBzOHHfcUql5s7VwUC6VNtza1svqYLDRfAZ7BP4rH7@1i5HffoZ/V80I/nxu8E81QpfekbZ7XrMHQC@vzG7LtuEB/kVqLdPs0V/4aViuE6ELyt9mpkci9YrovA6HqG3YyDyk0fpMuB3pu@hxRPpDR@VTh34jWohfFPha8JfOq9BJ2o3lUnC0lm2hyY6M4ds12aEaxQze7RjtIcqbPfRPKfyuoysJ2GYbMjquKYOXRibqdSPXqlQr7baVrhspW70ZH4GBcDrnqbrdaVrnRipVb7aq5y48tBr09DFyoHzBUZxnC72kUxW57Uo1l50TqqmWCPUYwUANezsbFLaK3FT6HDJeCIfoNZN8Q/XMjmtdm60hmfmZjXSENT5/vu75c3Sk2QvohgK7YXYDCqCOcFYmbloz0y/QoODFdEZcsSIzVKl2a1avW@0OK@zpuiK8dQidN8eve2ig6pS4oJW@29mnj/DDhFH@MKq6vxRirIfu9sPsKKS24fS0QyDZNIFfNMjTznjYVvv8R4H2wW5YftMPG3DVr3aH4dHOn7ik5KgySau/8rutw8p6aWv7aL98pwGgT@NSw3JBvjmaYyHRftHyUbVM1DCA5msK5lbnWoScYfsqzQre07ZMO@SxlaE57FJwVngSzZLqnkS4KvOUZ8JTrVVPPYRKxy5qDjywHCtocpbR/goLElO5yfe55vrdzb0xI1NrVTtX@FRgVVmQF7p1bbCEy1AFFo@yVF80/x0W9huKetY3qqHRrhoWyiAUYuUwH3VwOZO@vTCiiHDsAI6sVTRyWS@YgDDH8T5PS5Ub7ltc1iQCK/ir2u2TOSSHBuGK8HgmVihIj1LszUxqq2q9LnrYUE6htFagqaNMYgsS1c6kcXdruapHNB1IAyi8qawMhLlOVbPOhLHKWFoI@I7rnfEV9ZAjVYjQemTa6NkOIKEpZhw6lMY5wtqpI1hhTS81i0S8h9PsGQZC@Ul/WWLFXVxQ5C8OSUhceo0LNE41mn3IqTkMVXlTjwYKNbhxCC2ai4bFAWKlyzxvnDTgpxbiLWckCNuxkK@Pit66EKgXuKc80tccq@IawsyLcR0JoOg5u6mRrYZXNRv3BNtC5mC6t2qembyWBUIL8l0uQvVMXzykKKp6O6pLj7P7HARw@8axBmYrBgSzgoY4jgFJQmXJcfiBcij1pZpDOp45zQzw0aMYlDqlfJmFM@OpEcs9fx57lopR0pOFeFwtRlE8rxXXCgORXl42Yvnp2IwsPIuFAeSMH8BsOIA8A5idjuUkgLwAkJsDCMxiEJAnxgLPWj/gBQ2wgnvmz5ObD619Op/InT1/voA6nlpioHA@vOnTM4k8FGbQEwn/FwbLH7T0M3@PMG54XttHNBCziRkAwVUn/B@8WgMfVKV6nbNnoZvTD2NepJ2G3Hyo@AUQNrN7uoD9xZnKSumOAc8O2e5jotWB3cagvyqNp/Q0TnPgEQrCyeGFiUZTSeCTG70LsWnV0BmVf1fUjCMoB5IBQoKEYyWNy7v2utq3b3aYmY1Kuc9kV7oAYghQFKAYC1AYHeQjDqzzCvq1lPmyni9x3sCokh3yGs7ejZHtlzWxXT6hD2@4AV6d7ssrtIcwfmNQoLK9tYI/b8v7qDG7tbMBQziB/Uga3l9lU8sQVReFCSNFZoImfEavHTXBmyEKaaj89WOirF9Ak8BF/iB0Lki9wxzCe4jgDmleWL2KZQtojEo5j8we4ZFMEFWGBfT1P43esqstRMeQzToXhKXidEYAJlQ56BRQFBQNRAwhzg73SzsH67v7rwlze5XS9t5mCSGDgFmvdhvsPp6CT3XMFm@qCp8R3H4xoh/1qVpDKROlRqtdPWfzEJq9AnmQsUJfKpQabBH2lyf9SH5ODitAFEXlBqai0jCdENiou6qyic64IQB5FLnVYisUbQrbCWnDG90JJR1dRkpHuBTuQpsWogoEdaYnGQlvBaNvO2aXdzHko85pvnTZVcNMnvwkar5r2NO8Qn@VnLZJF1WMfQBptppUiaAsGqIwRGFo7z36wbYpau8VMIAxSvKmm1V8r8fm@plF4B4Zd9/F42oMEkPR3QoTD0RskaiZRszPOlp@lnFcZVzbJdd2CbUxwTUugwyZdXZ66WPEwtBjSfRcMm8sOTNmTwqeK0sYOQwG515goEE6C2GqQwOGw4T6Ql176KN1T@WQPZWr2FuJ4czd3UyZQKyfIxMbjrd/CoG50QC0xUbONshyRQSuZd8C5B7RvFH@D9jQSYoYlJ9mSgXYaZlPkk@0oRo7MxASUEOyljkV1Z3RpqLgxQRAjLrHGfTwZmSFKZ0qd4BaeMZpmiMKNn8nfwteIpJVsQt3G3KRU05vM@s2ggZdmAlT2eDQs0pgMz6uiCJjIHhEUsPnFRp4VvrAvGoqhab3fK5BPA2QW@wDNc/qhXdjYbQbonOSJ7PYAgZJnXjOMSnArF9B7oFUWXkhtN9aP6QxHBaOax3jAIG3nm3x0Z4xk5uZ0cx/d493jPl5zzp4u7x@aMzms57J8dbG5qExvxj5rnMy7zyB5yMuHDGgOK3YxUUO5lLdbLVgEfNPw8KtH9vGYvGAf4YFxVxNswTrCnIstgZXhRxBT9wmmlbmBrl0ZAKIIp0Bi/AYcvOGjOf9arfa6ZlsY0kulvhml10KQkHkYc2uyz5KUG0MKT5F/XX7GKcXD4AhpWHXSUkSYVA5GOl@m7SRksgwXJtddANg9YSh/wTRHDEdmDQs8ySQiZI4LMu5wSgUJIFWNB6yMBppW0bs8dGLeMoTu3K4naVWHm7naEujc98qsxWEXjFVCMf8HJkQCB7ZZkgen@axVvuuyuyR/rCjwdFNhoVTKYcLMLzHjEr@1lnIYQz7iNX3oIFQYiJQ1KezuLSBIwogTaDq8hyCM9HP4KwQkbBYGkUMoqcn6SqNaARxEbRL0ZaC/l/RDQVuK7a00Z2Q2g0xms9FWH1xoRkwFAZzyjxS5MApH@ccwjYymAPXJ@cY6DCgFbxQYYdQ@gcDhKHs3ZB80wyRUjg@x2VUHTzRIbmW2C5uP9ukhfdCrFGqtBCZCGkpfYprazk8G3dZZMPeadmgUUSPZKdktqM93W05Z6TW04HUXY331fbQxovqRjL5MPHApitE@NyQB4BCYRkwXdqYSTZTGx9mkmAQVdQkmLO07sVRhcCBpArcuppWgnlmWUZSEt03/SjJEbnUw3RemgNLgq6OOT273rCO8kyWXZXdpBFEYtVsWQ5tjf6@imWh91W40/d19pnWWWll7OtswAf/qH@HDjw0MXaYCu0QFZbL0SeNpPGkgZchIkXfo5Rv/hD657d11hbkr4reilT9U20lo1n1wmtV3B0iadfnO5ZDuFm5yHPxOG8BOcxudwpSuZ5LkZ96ZGeA6fGVy8fFsbOazhJEs1ngkLc4JQ@38xKSN2MIStH4NcOhLeiz2fVlltm@Ep3HBsRV3qYFPdXyarNIUGbfIvU89huxRELsZ0XfabBnQD12IupQBO3UTJTvLE80ZbQVQ/zG22Q4DFlEbPfe@i/oDRmObQiig@6IxF6n7ozYJcLtz70Z9Xg3R3BuwHc5efjzqeD5V4NPc1nJB8Qcj19Q0gHLAzpvIBhtyQziwRbF8HCUozRnfH7Pw8gnv4N29ACiFyNXEzpB4hbmNbHI0YSY0WbS6BBGORZloN00kHQQoqBzN5465OAtk0/hNSA/olPIQK984AwycqbTuAI7/yBWFr1qkpyqe//AgZ/GzuOVpSdnOWgcLLUd2A9n22mZbLmT266UdreUa6vx0dY5Y@RAuK1KmX1c5@ikir9UykewlaHDqV7aODC9SITIln0kcdLsxz9iIfSA1YHMGGjT7NQpYGnvBvUHBAA3rTfW9eLID2275rW@KixzuAFJFWX@HBDTr6WhAZl6teeaQzODBTO1FvxpVzFqVgZE8gz2MLPbMbeh9AHGvEpfVq@rkTWtYWQ5HagV@b2lSArPjuhLr@qYrD1CAeXJzWnNhrFR@qlCSKDwNxQxsYMuAM6rHF0MdpQBOoAVwRBJ41Zc6pDKg0lyxGx2cZ6IvSt2OCqH@3c6Dd/m4pFqv3eBATNgdbs2TpeuSbqpVNyn0xLQyeCF6VeiYDnfn1ZH51z362koFY9MRitrdx6i9xGm46G7qAzT/Mhk8HjUaVWHRvQGZhbqqKzOPsvOL6GsZZ13aBriaqE4uB7Hbg6crgk57E4U93FZtmVemy1jBofxreX2IeNBrw9diojQbDJjbGbJwGo0H10kX/ss@r1Ptt3ypzTRbsLwJGq0TDOM3Jgoe4BMkSz2BRMD58Gfn1Dl2bYdYwkeGmatf06bQUyLtYfWUdVkDQtU48uxWvwn@F2C37h04dhHt1Xo60z4r0J9ItsyTmGZn3l@DwsR6gUs/SK3vhD5VmfUfEoAuf2hw8RBgdmRWRr21i6e2lCFrFwsv2AXOXZI/IFeHYEkoL8pnJjkAiuTkScjU6WpeEG9rEzxVzo1ivGzd0QkHTJKdEj9hRCXkYTOELeLQgcEORwVrFKEKBMxxzyNFEB9VEphd4HVGjBzT04aOJxmuC9p3WAF7zM@7RIsSPBz7kzeYUG6Fnct4PRS8/7KoznxIM/bo84v1Rzh@HoESzrW5vlACf7ZIE4T6dA0qQ5UPS@lFBkReU4ONpY0BsY5nr6z@JQ0huK1Yd90CNKgmE0Oi7lCBEkf2iqYnX77CwojSS7Sd5KY@dYwgdoXIvhXSHRdrlytbtgliKwjIY8QocCkU5nOQfGSRu62wCH2gMZLEp@XwXb03obqYn3oILylUxBF6P9nvE0sPcE4k1QfXhnQQ04@5M@SXm2MRNXqwdC@ig2SQ4xsj/ZIy0LqwGdxOE@vQ@0T@SgR9zSCwOA5bKWK944VxF1MeeKtDIogIFWGRTzDY/9fyPDysiAHMph/yYCMqRRmRGfhktml74RmIH2DRAK/g1Dn/953llDKluVHvuPoEXwur8O/9ZzkER4qg2RlGJd6KVCiMpwmFCj1lNuR7lLzfkZ/R9ob6O8IPlR/x@BD9XcUn9/VX3Vi/I46AlsM/aCMgyL7TyBRQ26VyOcUPxmYmPV2qLWTYOm@A70IlsbGG6OlbYecyJpjWsB1hjSCvmvpUOdPXMcSPMcpLBORpIUsLL1z4PjdCC/xro38YoyeK/CH9y/gJ1t8ti32aEpAyIt0oq9eU4F3qEA49PUlSZKo@odVMU1ldgI985N@cdHQqiqohlNHWQYzqLDqfdzgVw2G1vWCCMomiyCi4kZYkT7yHVguWATTwosIrAv66C@FWDdCS8lBxNIyFLLAMpGd6JaIyKy47qh211Qh6gzTVeMnlByrznsHCTnBeTDopHcqIXdpEMW2mnTatsqK2MaeOJ1CsycKote1@@cXBjqKQh4Q83YCIUuAqzehoX30VbMk1eJiXvfV@XHGOHIMEPLJfh5X7us9Y9Ukz@h4liyCEWrbhNCwmpiQvJMeuJoovcp8xgd9fOLgVU9jpjVgDecDNIEcMEP1@zSdQiqWm5geAhCDcbadHnLWFncBu@8Vc/AaxiuIHID08UXMyoTKGt5YnsZaa6l1enO3YaqEtTYb2kgyQw02smbiUV/2jsbxKWLw7Aaag7Vja9bM38H4qVr59hrk/numJlQqZ2WSQ2dRsGecjg00zWtbKLFQOFacqSCBA8gdu4uy4TAZCvkGz@NodVVvQPYiURnzJdKiORcgz16jolFoabpxI2/iZDqAgKAFxFrx3Rnel00DMcDSr0kcVYVZAHaJlUO/s9wMu463zLLwKCYw7rXZwPjW3SrOFWpnDM0bxHKVt4QNq3ougg1I0iubQ@fRJC1eWHW2yljdw6Z0OQQ3CdvYmjSMJen9wFRYvTDrV5QX43x40FNWJwVo6/RSdtNwP/WrXZMibRuJKTciaDzvNPtCEyfIRwkCVfBlpplXHGVCtMzIfqIryMC0kud1eFQjaR4p62yaXXPKFRF8xZkR4lY/@8FTk7QB9EodyMD23BIWupZLcDTxO2lgXEMYDNtJ4zekhP7O6m/IWNYeFdmJoa@b2osvExNW/1cNolBD6SoIMdrGxU7MlOb@7IsjubGqMZlTnFvJWBp@FdIAlT68@a53yCjIO7@Az3R@HuN4GCJPE3UtuqYQIbBMNp6kSkbB0lY8CrVjd1I6ZM42ChjyYbb4Q8ev@HsaPwMZoA7SHiAwaP6OJ4z1Kh5WUtOF9AkrnXqJE1l0BegARt6tdky777aGv@uJEJkYoF284J0haUivJ@LVz46jGMbSWQaDARhbmV1Sd0PdBBTUgXjnt5fwS/RQkBocuLYt9lmjJcxgXJD3gPyYDbomih3it23xDTdHqRMQ@IIuE/CkB9UEemTjlWS1ASCdZC7W6aWpnFSwq9Z7fSKiFzYqV6BOad@kiN1tICOQTkOCBBv7gsBtx@xyZTDbhnbfkPszzFfP1ScQSM/XpgWViq2P4CNtxm7hvOeNBOAgbA0Uqhyem1oZIL/QcMiuRWul7Q2mCJ9R4ObGt1tA//HKKkvVwi/CttgGzqvwu2vjWzg888UqEXagXBbdCsBi007JROCSR0K@j0tBP6D/JOMiU4LMyxNK6PbjTQJpVYwey0kB1iqQokXMKqKmxnO0sIB1CVlPrbNHRbxrYa0NOjvDUbyBCWJWu/UL6BKMl4UTptclPDWshqHilWD0PHGZ4RoAvoi1MgPd6bdr6JKmSfhSZpp074GH5JAl5oGOU82e6aVFFM5KwHz@gKqedH7ciKu1xVWRXILCD2RU50i4g4o2VTgeEiEG3z3NJoWdZky84lFIHtGC76ciMSVCrQGGRj7lz6TneiXy5QtBiLk7IMYNLaiJzyQsQqGFPRWnG7t7xTdHeOzmyuiEyPWqsEtuRAshFRqSSR7OeWFNaD3jxnJR7d1/yCtnUw@IYosNethwykOwCrInlZaVNnKW5xaQsDqfQGXEJ9SM4rJ8c8mEXU0eeefKZ4hsG5TVTbcErov6UuCxFkeZbNfWbTUFd@WbGyKnmBEUPFW0HI/fxZGkrCNFYCgXN55lHGp8oiizFYS5U0pPuUXxn9sp0SfmitlZzsrVyPOjWOTZ4dWhlITrmqrutDRvYH0yH/qxy8OiCuDwfXgjisHHqQVjIPS7yNJqwBpeEwH52@AenyJLOjEx/BbsEC6UmrgWxolms1gGJHcoZcA8z42AlCcJ4y@h0P4EQ6Hhhbfmzoakqo2ueQ4/@xa2qOFOIb@kbr7TkTU@TNzb3do5LO9X9stvy/sHZSpJivzKoLjvZOikzL1B594dAXfK9TnEiRx3LdjHccehOEsogR/U7V7PWAdx1wRx/KoKJat9MzL2zj2/Pf7bkWt2l7j8oQiGjcb3pGnsWmgi1EdVJejfDQvgfD0cc@M8@WEPJIdUqPXaQk8GHBcqgjQTiDl/QfqJK6lm4zUvSxjCsgG3FLvZu0EOUEgT/jtm2GlaDVjNZlro2MrceOTg@UtQDhGQAYDvqHU7TEdOgIfS1ypGMbUw3FiV2or0nGTv1ayxx9WuUbXGGvcLechqy@6cR4T3BK0FxLnBpgVzzjSXJIrJKAiqQL0F9BSImOYecYcyKB9kculs5se5NPAusf9A3gq@wyT/O@28R@30Q@MnhZntyxgAvsBtfhs6X9ikUAu68GhNfoO6QEV5UdH3mZOPtyYX4Gf@wBbkYwzIRetmfz9G4z/WnvvBZtY/28fC798MJ3QC@6xy5PQNVTG9/XEGO38qViPfZi5ynxXFL6YT4aYTIqDatxhPULxxwCJyHlu7fGCPR03q@MeV2t0inFGAJ5NUy6doqyLY@JXmvXg0QhP5YUr0Pg16n1r570wdfnxfQ2wBvO6Gqx1/Q6814whfR7PfpAmvAvXco@Kua@vf@tov69XV9lGlvTtE3tM7SMM1J5rrV5EmavP1q@FTA2dLF9bxpekvNMyVeYt0Kq8dxklldLF3yDMzLhlQf@dDwZDSKshbT8TI4vBa/hBzYrbqNokiX7bgU4gXclRcwrodxV9Abd3DoHdYSk7E9EN80dbYNOIGA1HR3oC2B/HgGPlAeoex40D6h0aOxbjKxEIbsQlRN/B/V6yt1BRkA49fjKz@gEZWv1iN/GI18ovVyF1WI5OPMn23m6lZnQywZi0jdQPcf2QSFtTarnG8WTo0DjfLxvrR6ivjZPfIOC7tQMqusXe0sr21asB/5Z2DskEF1L@3ZhdV7g0Y@jWzbtLpfD6bnTUI8kiA8lnjoNo2Nu26eQ2T57lbbb@44Jd0x@wtc6nytdkd2nwd5KAyS09YTdBZEd81yRMntLiuwUxu4z2i9OWJbSRvni6fLJHtBYVDVwbcfLdHPAjpcdG1kjLagPw2pAKYKl/Jku40Xq0T09JIGwJx6t83YxCYwtcHRmlnDSN9rm0dbu3uHBjru/vwuneCbnaMtS10G7NyhJ8o4@vdta31rdUSJXADsmkDz9bIYP2uJqQxO2GlftXsY3iwFkqF4s3n1XsyEunY0irCNab6Hc99TwOmFN67s7PTArlojz0u7W@8Ra7G/GREoxjkUnOoLiwQHmfRaARqE1G0C@xMHVnLVI4JUntoPMbPhQidAdFz0pDA43RPbJlGdBWPEfFCmuJmM8MmQUNFjwA2gpKOYIsGRWCYmko@J5DLUBudHsja8GC1KV@w6AvhmBXlyEnppdUloBiccatT5zC6MgHmPWt1U7W9LmfAAyGRwBnwDAYTetUrcwsPSYw5kaPfQ8EfEuY54bLtrN8g14gGriJhhQOBLIg28bjRkGKAo6rV4XH0mTUxdaAYKVTEpfzoJKfVkkeupBIH/L@4Y8NbWcgZBSrYhJUthQrv2g1mA9D2i2qz5xqxYhxPg0EEMTsWa2qdt6og7tG5cBcNlq5RjYCqXSjiv2XpqF4ynBSIU4owtaHhb4cqtyY2fvOh5aDkykiNqLdHnUaFKRH/6d4GrIw04HvAAKCUTi/QrZDTI8aWwNhNMZVjrg0zEkQ@49f@qEZ2o183fQWErBO7tD5/jgskJ70imooPtU5p2GGoB7wIuUEfVOTmAoQY0pS8wNsoHsOYvwfe3XAblSG62MCPErmiNl14kDUKTRxRKfLzY2qtVckY7t5aacazbrAiX47yGUXX3y6b5dE1SQ3FZCXNuejPGZUY0LNTF928NA1ULBr2qCUc3CHi0Y5fG27m9FcLxeW1lQ@pX39MnmUy50wWqg2@vGClRL5mIZEclofSnSRtQLnSBNCI269haanPyNQSV7kEBozLhQXM94tKQX3jY9XR9A7Fy/KnU@LXr0UulSJ7E5pCGEnGo25J41RWmaQyZ0ZcAPBoJzQWPevKlCTBVPT6Bca1x1EoAEY6SEdIvUYPq0b6NZq3a7zQA8oSEXwaD7eCH5exyMWMon8xfTwyv4qtFBPL8YzMRYtJoTMmSXRSQs7FRa9ucXhpvxoBt3Y3OKDfDwe3cGfreHv4Jmhrd0L7pralEuNh8bakwXo42F/fAZY3t@8CC31PjgfMm@QoNDXT1eRMPp6Uc/6eGj@OjB2tPQCDey9GVFVAtdr6nRZ6iIvxoTg0jQrEdTAeQ3RwuFbe3zeiZTxlW4KyQPeqnTrZlyIZRNiPpKcjtkMmYpdWTJMKE6SYJ5lyy@al/mrvWsyhyBtDKgQPkhT4UMRCRe0FyWQgrCN4ZyEWAg2vmSBKzPlb90XSIPdUAL49RU0owxs0rYOR0G5O8ubDTvaJyHh4SzJv7F5ZjmJmzIFw1kVH1d2hDkgywrgdVM/x5jt8/I6ZP16S9TCDZX7qU4dRCb@O/vKNA6jYwZvitH8E7xgWOaSks0KzdFLijszy/Bz2z59QKhb7reCFNbIumGPRNOaPH2uR7Ig/fYH3/EPxsd4W552SxFPKc31A496mF/NvQcBkghhsvNBnBRQ/uxVbGGFD7ZNFxZDra@0xteZUtpKimQnYhfGZngAHPzcfJA/BqoDa3llV6sdUxbuEryYt7tZoDfIjQJ6fm5u5D3awF7J46ufC5j0kSD97bee6qoF0hy6pCsHM3dpJyu/eBLgDdUWQAhsxuWACBYHVCdlTfH2nzUhvH7Tlpou2eNCY3aPDJJ4XBWuNG4NA28Kh846kQ6csI33QlrDqKK@aEezf3l3dCgV1u6e@R99eHy82zITn4be/5TCZ@7aDpBIY8W6FvaKCSL7kolZcD0tw8EHl6VeLgflCxrE85XhzL/iGG22kucYXPfsK9fpl5EwR2yyK11DpdtX58hUPuL7SkSl/Q5sAUdZKGi8uWUeFI2u@aNikRNBUoSxfcCv9aUDmryt68M0lVB@kb5xBu8AsKgROPZ0yQO5ZwlMFGWpyKsFpwJ@opBQnwVztoeyh0qc5He0SLKc1VOkZTm@YGHhOpT4XUG6qKuLl1LLIGYyQORUVmems1moOK4R29fkn/gxsjEp6IhoDsmXLVqmPOBV1qmTSqSjb95LOOAkkKZU0KXLhxmT19LnkmuZVhQZZRJsDgFNJo2O1ztJCf@qnmJAd48KEo8cDCeXNTiNCg0IxTxUouSW8QNeyYgqdvrDO0qRAKQgQymTewPJCemF5BfTMkK6FvuRJxcWoAfhXNEI0VZ@8WPPpi0uc4V3TrfdNozxAGV/GRpSzkhyDTBrlnTVjd93Y390r@0FjiyvIo1ApqbBHoZhFw6g7cskmYcDtfu@iwonyNfj1xuSvEgS/q0wdu6tl4tfgV1kBgTjDZWl8@dr4apzC5u2oQYk14mdi0GWPVR/Sdbvf6X35OvhKwzsATi8NU@An4zaNhwQ/jaBFrETBYcvpQHdxGBYS@cqKdKvg1UIpVMtA@OawhcV1YM3HbwW0iKKfMHSwMolIewE5gUwiJbCR5VkS8S0BHfULL@Am3WUXjVgs2DDclNLpkeSE8UwFbjT1iLv@yh5YSWJcJYteJTzDFJy0i3FEvdriRsM2vlpfZWXepoJb/0JQ2lHYRt/NYhi1LYaWnS9P9kz7zLcSWp8bEf/TyIITI2j4442K2w1eEBjk3aPmRZ7jvmw0v0eyKeIgs/ECGslHq8CXkZfJSEYqPwqxEt5Kb@mFFAlvsbceR5szphYPXEiR8Fq8RvuHwlvrgdGo28CdcUASfKiAIKjtr6EjB9NmpOJxi9UIFhRTkcSZCtcZ4594SB2STHMOmI9n8jF3xqY3xpRe7M78fozoLRCd1xCCNIjcqeC2pqfngun6lmQsa8WDObRGBTIDzMBOdf9YsCcRX9INWmrxsiKjLRENHHktsTUCyTnTstIUGpM15c/Kq8bLC1kxC3FxuLNoWXkl@rMmwrNqk5/y61ADbdVWo8qaCM@qrY8RqKkwqP6siWDWEbpGhNKPe8XQTsfuHrz4GD5WB6dVZQ7Mer/HO410WgFrqAfLQ2e0RO6GdW71fjI8Roue0tAenLSzC8IjtkwDAX/umWJ9qIBktfUmiGo9gEgtNF7KCqmYj6N09s1jzBXz6MvPIa7xflzLeko59GEw2AOTaIhkMoRAI3cxyYrpqOFSg55RIGMkI2pMfoHXW@R@Tye/sLjDkd@jyWj8NsrNKvioKPRJJgv56PlziYt0z65YRui/gmg8wbAdww8j7SXd8c8Ho99TqXjEkWzZdT7sTCKsghTWTiEdBXC62AnAwNuU0b7IggDm7P524IXKKAxsQsK4q1M6DClUjcKYfjAMKbCNwkg9vB0kT4X15cmDYbAgGAYj82AYOANHcRqd/AIAbvlvNGyq@fCBZlEitZqs@aeGgln1vdWCfZGiqoH2ggTBl38QeAtrh2DM9bne0sSgB@EDhY5RfMQsXknLsBUT5c7yAXMOS8ZH1gsLt5TKJ7DayisYj91eAzaCdLOl1nfI4g@I6IFDEgGQzj1QiEnXL7ogIuFopoX0IRkQggntr1RQNatSoZOhvf3djf3S68pO6TUKUZNMo/D4BrVlSF0nm85jPHs@bamQTlHRQFUL7EaE6LD2jdonwJRpF6HIsVhq8ouW7zbKDBTWVKTzonTHvDHW4RMFrR@BiTnT6mwGhidGbVBEPZq6jsa9nPoOJnsl5LVlaAnl4XkiWkJ5tOSIJmxx@Q8d1lD50PnQ44w145RtMt0zvb0f0HBJK2gYqesPvbdmt4a6JCnltJRHEVXwUXYj51SociFO0D0I2gD@NpMxVqRTXGG/Vm3V0eVtv0mOb9tWq9quNapp58KJNN2icE8Tm2q66OQygspUW4fl/YPKHsbpKq@S5QT@K9C3w63X5d2jQ/xyAJ9mRHJ5f393v0IK6vtHe4foMTSQFNUzCiheNpHgy7Szu1na1vLwe1Q0kg1CXJA34Ue48kkallMZ0N8hmXkkWRWiQkF4yEwFi1Ja0uhZbdPuy@Bt6H9CbvBJtDzBSxmoS0Y1Joc0MTz@FN88X6e3Wi5qR7fv9CgracDHApiI@0twnrZ7jgXIF5ELfDtp06f5RBm/oSGf7cQCZdFABotFhH1X06XVgcvkYNipxyQ44cgz@cXsQE68bZrq95qphanbOHqVdEhpKFh4KgM7R4aco06FlxQYFFrpES2IkX7sWohIg3fIRRYlNAieZQoV4BvEgpFIWPEvET1AlPgEVJXjR30xNBt6fx4Rv2ZCGyN2a8p6vlA/ThD1JCxw1Bzh1z39UoommLifImOOU7Q8VzijX9lZPmGOqdGJ0f2UZ9edRu2RVWhwqRdjRy/ks8@bd@K6SzSggh@CI@7/BuDF3ZjoMFXIc9ztFQBRve7QYAtCt6fQBT0/w78D4dq1jgo0MZhwcT1vNMpf2R0lGgm5Pc5AYl50ObrkubFhswSlOMw5nus5cmE5fqXnyIfluNZzzITl@M1fcBarGUsk5OAtG/m5OdZm9o1nSPF/q4qnUjLvc6kK7RUGeHpxuRszkDLDELkTRTQH1fdsAK63bP7OlvlB/@bfAWwdliiVokq44Xc0@w7If/v3okt8QvcALP1v3EONQCFzIq682IQZzwtXxRSXTRK2pEFo/@EOaNGoHMXwsv/MmxG/GjNpfvMffXnCp81fynE3FP7kDdeEVzbnWTUEAfz7UQDFbwFQ4fJyfZG3UTbgxc/5JQVF9sADwFlm9Cz5YJawKr/eWWVWh5cLrTKnZ8k@pMrf/GdRp9i/QnL8S5WDaK1AZmjW/8@30Eg1HwqFZXU5J9rU7Hm3vmOzn/vboBcLy77nQaciZ3e3@2//LNhur2Ro/v8@dHJSAX1@yWEPRfz/9VAYM2NhfGQQqdRYvE1xjkRibI7f/I3XDkZvcJndtUj@9h/cXzo7vvR/55X2tvlluXEz1yCBBUmgUg/yf6Sipwoajx8gQKWEtEbbRtWa05Yc7sXCYMzfgZz6LCzO/J/z8vMw9POM@hwAfssMluSS0L8eMUbPOcIgsUbeM1n5MsMlPy4Xda4tzh3SuV1m1oWBOeBG8TjCFEdjepYDAse0T8gYBS2@xgWzdxshLrgQKvy41W71olPFAK2u3UmLCCCWnSm37UsLN6puBt1cpC/dcdLQz2GtCQDJcUUUX0uoUAFNFU5FWPeb5XbMWK3X@@1@C@/QikKuQsdImQy6jCNBsNNvuwIm7rgrfasFPSgip@axiCDmOdBK2oWBlX5Q9YGqw6odrTKTYb3xNLmhoyRqW71rOT2qrDgqC6DLJ2JQoQrruZZXsvBooP6FALEr2qLoz7bVMWNafoziaiW1BPKLkChyqQLNjCBONBhJ1ADZ6bd9EL6IESfdmCJ/Sbto8RPLJvOIORPnjdE1MUKIso6wXCMvfNCRaxkEIiyIun4o@eRsnLFEgPZgerb9OWaT@SxW5OAnclFEnqGVZnm1SW6LyKiVYBA0lZtGAThCD7zA63IWegcfVLuK0f/213/xf0TjXzIZmUYxdaxOFWQGikjiQcXXQ3tPvmvgUT4RtooB2P@nB5tBN8y61a5ihJqeBhom1xjIMIAI@QtMNHRaZbeA3tjnMc0XjKwQJ1YmU1pbMw4393eP0RqKDxFoFgSK4yRYMqIJRjuV9H0XisGYRcyE0TyvRcWYSTZiNJfqFWZTPSb3Os2YpoEF2PpH/wNhi87ybdR053UZAIifo@zUB88JUbdWB6sGQs5gHId/9A8Zsu2w9mw4YNuJiokJj44Jk18eRcZG@sU5wuv7L//8f6bqhEUJ8Hx4rtLWqx7H9NPXU3EgS3M2lTsb2ytfNYSEsYDvRdGf/ysC5nKQbkkIIxM6VVRAwrv9L/@JQTDw8gFGTytp@OAk7gX0lwxI3R4Q5sbCS90L758yvIZFtwA6oNrQ38XXsE@mu2g0FNOSM/eg77/8c9FiyG/18M7kjjqmfc2NhA7Gv9FHlsqK4Rg3vhr8sSP8L3Sgwsx1HETeqELh/MV/9pap3k12nczze0JbnYGmhXb4L/5T2OwjHXNYPegBnMHqQxW6Vsa0@X/9xwr@IDIxuGfC/Le//qu/8fo4GNuzwdj@/JW3mgajvRiMa/tEgCS9wy0jmhiMHYr/6K/Gt3IHRe11HID/MA7vAz@yB@OWPEx9tegH9yz7cUD@UgJRC35w75IfB@ufSlihiz3YrTHLfTB2mUvoYxZ6AP70mGbCYvzX@mIc3DXyY9f8@GnxvxNwZPjQeHRkWDIZweFkibV9buToFz3z4u9ysDU69cOjNo9xKQJHBeBQavLNPcw1eK6v/C/BmPK3zNd4qTnhbEH2SKslJ2oB0aTackOqKhZ/WF15RB2IeyG1LH9fJZHbTKZjstF932mg1EH3d22SPLp0/YfBA8Ip45/RWAK3DeIKW9uQe4JTavIZ3eC4I9MHwZHPISlqoAfoBogb9PtcdTeV4xSSNyaCUFo2s0QTdJyOotBYQURIEoncWahQwXJq6EL4fxQFYumqxtIVIkv0kfzIel/uJd5//jeKIiks2X7oAZCJ@2H@32IYSMWI7srJY4fg6caDLvrelCDlT5VbwNit@//VqUWguvG8pJZtHOR/9j@qjc50UZe1Af1Bk1fy@I/BMRExY3dAjX7yIwGIxac9kjG25v9JDrzLFGpc5biTPaCeMdX8q78fxakdjiT@XLhfyBIQx8pYxtaOcXRQ3jd2jw73jg7xQEZ3jKhk8PGCHovdTJdJgPUfEozIsgUQ8/MszmrfeHpZSSuRj1P3/5e/wu4z2EQxmo1qaLqz3L/wlcvJcnfgiIbiwRgS@Bkpz4cW0DquW/S2WFwQGAIBeqvTw/XqmvAgsvHBBDt8FnsbT382mdalblExw3nA0P/IbmmHMeMPE3CrwwEo5gwcv2L2l5nx@5kZdGQ1xNu7YthtHsOHXkiXn5T19z2DfCeb4Qe@Nzc36SaGp@p3rbTponsiFx3DZZxzYBY6Nh1qottsmHhWHWRbdF7Yr195T6l6tXNddVFB5qcBqkQXF58O@Tcy7ozYOW9zKI7vPSc2DDrtTQ6T9SQAS9bqV8nmTaMgPrBhsFI44UTkfrrype3KJ8tpqhx2D8/Z1ada66put4jbjdZasJFFvaq5hzLnUL6Kd8diwxh5iDwU3k8NYppjrEhh4KUBfYFH4KqkdbE1OB2e@YoPVHGfNovLETHvBMoKwfid9TgobMCAvw@8SmW1pwPhLF6ZkOHtAyqFyJwIZijz@CzC8cuAleKX8YYK0zDn0JeGlj/1IpWW@OY3GMeinBgwJxxAuBnLnP7qw@mHs45r3kyfJTLnSXR0hLlrwqyRcEo@e/gZsd@6bjm260vqmG6PFVyyMql@IWYDzxVWfBG4CmjcQLOUwo3lIQ21A4v0EUl0qRezhJkqaeNc0PV29DTq4Zgbdioag5i2pJKBSMOLJ83UXgd0pgHCdNUlGYkvTBcqetxFf1oybwpwjg5gOkM0I8RADf6lImKYGrf@VuFtGScA2tkHbqAr8jsMxWngk9bNWzH@evMffXPzm7AuwltPE5aJYkBpbGACwTXFcmGPmMtFbVyhBZnpagtd/kXLHXJPIxUH44XpjDRN4XqwCyLorDb4deF4gm9SO0ILBesaouxrDIu8LHldSJQqTRPvFp6@y4kgyjMB4QgiIcVMUWygFwNJlwkHXYuFFbvRGjmgRg64COcejGnkmSiGgTx1tw1n6LStCvsRwMuxRi@JhYZbvcb4VOyKaDqj6vRoDs0CaWEIA4rzrH4WWvup1miNaAUA4EQcAdAwm9V@q7cUCRK8XEq9KRrFqJQ0it/ENGBaAROMSHCBlcpiapKJGws8SrfI7SU8nUaiuWQ2maP/Zfm/aFImyv9yo4lZf86cPzGbDPzvd5J4hpgNF4ty2VkkyJH/Hw).  Code is in the input section.

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001390 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9534 bytes)

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNLliD2uXL9D/wllNQtZopkkkm9KFJklUol3dK9VSW1pKq691IsVpJMillKZvJmkhJZKl302EbvPBb2bk/voLfHO7d7vIYH8AI72LWBXcwABrxfF4P9DXc@GQPD/Q/a55yIfPEhqbpnvKZEZmTEiRMnTkScOPE60TL83m9@k8IPO3LtybntDtnQ9Ies41mXpqexJxP22LD89eKqJCHUjnc@6pvO0C9LKaYzZjltqwPvbOhemI71wfTAv8jYwHPPPaPPhj1jyEy/bQxMn7mj4WA0ZG53frRVxvb67nsrhzH7lnMOYEPTG3jmkMLXGHvl2Ea/1TGmQtanEhx4EO6zp6b9sf9xyNpuv284HR8gNxh74Xq@ifBt0/ddjL7J2HjPbE8hLQGo4Vnu852Xn08FbTH2OZBoDGxzzIyWP/SM9tByHeRJgZ28fHVyNBVD19nr0/39ad8i@zLnOmx/1L6YDlplrzzfsI1p/GtsZzR0D4bT/uts59x0DFbUtrTidOAGe@IZM1E2mWcana5lmxoUCMuxnmkPTI@hD@u6HjsAkuxSoVRo7kQxtTbGLUWB02i3mL26OpzKT7EAjHe9nukAhYXpQD0MnAoohgEdixIwvAlT/J7rQT3y2Mg3O@zK9TpQuRx7omYhPht/YC3DNzfWEMFqiODCca8cqERDF4q2NRmazHGdHEVGwDWmP29OV6ziOvruHB5M@2@w4vNpv02oaO2L7mxZFkvs2B1Mpn232Avr@bzqvFrgDWHX7UBpTIXp7MgAL0omznhqnkee2xm1sekMeybExOaGpelLbSj@GhuIRq6hg6Wo/DkYoD5x@2Y8NZ85JrDXH5htq2u1ebUwx0PT8SFBX2MWkHBl2TbrmDZEiLC3s8x3sXAir5Zt9LS2JmG1wlRY/8JmFmsPBowHMdsCkvYLJWZi3tkHCLd7PhsP@sy3@hA8bLvdrmmyD@agB9Gljisx@LQHU9kK35ZNgHHMgDXmAJozssbF1g98Cjh05RkDqPe@4MHQ6oOwsoZpn5mGb6E4hCi@6XSIq4NQULrMSFRYdmlBc4WsjzzC7ZseNRjCC43LMwGlEYoq5cqzhkOq82yHHZmGx04901STQjORJCTmYgpDzIhGhbq9nd473E9D4fIYmjGAwvRWT3/0hWQwrcqWmxX4VmW5Iu29fMqul8/QzWUkVICBpxgqq37H/PzZmQnfsd7Kn3s3EmCVgCs2y7uDYd7IDYDA3BAIzBvoRFfusqgN7FjCbHuqLGJVjkN1oDRAdLDXWcpZe@R52A9ETDUuINO265wDPyGz3shBfjhsowBF0HZBjGeZeQlcA7lJZQStGjl82rOg0Hwskliz4L0ZMRT6M6jGgqNBur5rjwgOYvpDrMvAFYiKGA@67DXrGpaNUSAcUXGqPdMf2UOMM3I6WPLQW5kdjQVktKHhAlDfvYTkDEBKHlD1@7F2SUQBMBSES1nFoB/@6Z92zs8Bz067DZJJVNfXrOO2qd81iFjozBhWWBCHNpEFcFlMnUeHBC4N2@oYQ0zemYgkiAhK9cod2R3mQoLelQWttGdcQsuGxtUemryS8646y/rGBZcmFq@5kPG@0YKCpQQobcp2jj3ehVJqm1KK6kyuPxp2Syw32GNpP/9WeVRWHi2dmUCcqqkry/n8eQUqnLZCXvCWvq3mvN5JdDD@0PBdqyMNJsOe6xRZrs3kdtUdmI6STuBIZ9NeK61qKOUUtWJV21rXcjpKehvqYg0STquVdrVdt8qNylT0eJKA5grRYHM1lbYqSyByqFFc5vsgizUQ7a9zwhULc/0mshyDtZg3Mmba75J7pEhVwXrpYgUBOaT5tmkOlIKmqygmEG5uvjFgXk6ncIgMl61GJp1KZ@JZJwyQ00RGsbGeWi6KLXvQwy4HmOL4A@gJPKy7behnUTL61hD0xSxrUb2mXgQkC8nEKzPtmdghh/WImiRvchg/h4JSYIiaULIlm51YQwYhAG156M9IY9u9ggSJJuxmQHQ4mKhxDkUDkXlGdnhGeErkk8wSVxMAW8tkpVzLgkaAzQ1kuqjzsbwB@GqRwwA23khisqdvTABLm3erUYNhVhfaUh/EA@gybRNlDggfk3comMiI2p8PGjLqyoVccX092cZmmtjQy@/kvgEh/SF/a0vCzO8klAboebrmFbMN53xknJtcj2JGu20OhkJQQU78IYii6f6GPHOi89T8nrT8eDpt6kQC1SJKA4U8Lz3RFRooXYSanrNBmDJDDDRA7/NALNmT6dQB4HIqcfkdgiQIeCcvICHQAKCSmWOzPRqCVIMKfNWz2j2os0idw@Ui74SmkweveOog2XPdMGkkRq89LEpaPvRCMhaiyGGJzuKBzhVR1RIeVPhxj9sxG35/DmI3JBE6gpivljc0qHt34Oy7jjsHKTAyRIsgyRBeDqCJnaBCCR1XoHZRYw21zLCIoMxQje9g/esNhwO/DP2ENeyNWhrUlPypNzkYHjpYWfJDb2INXe5u2W4LxLIP7TMfpJBvj1rWeCpD5BeW4XtfugQFrOuzKvTc346g1inprg8Ck/x3ETgWJJPgJhT8VwZAAtKAUUrXJ1G8D0LlZOK0FVmjpqRBo5OzTMaGK8NgRcZYIV923T5KIfaGFAPU9GDQZjmo6QuZTyLfmNvVhbKf9Lp0WnvvWo5ynV5aWkqX0zWQ7EtLj8C1ja5H6MqA6xG5cuRCOA1dFCNLLgytUwz0a6Rv6gHmsdrAYhtjr/TBGihGvVxebWSNui6eRXyqIOpAsgF0Dh@AJ61Wq@hUVbl2BRnVWt1k7ndROp@0PWsgmPCFcWnwd8GFVWKD1R/gINAzK9jJ3s6TftWDXhCU1nZP8dJn9cJZ4@z6rJM5u0lnMbZaMaotyBSkp/S1c88dQXep1tfKOb2hqvVV6CRb1XQhvaIopZwNCRmq@llJzRic20raBKmtnJ2lgamCP/V2zyN842xRVUNWAR3YMYNOqKS16xKk31IbaiYNcdV0FoYY1XQaONNGJviUaayZCQYdHn/JGbObyUhUDV3vAr8zYh/8NBhg8ej7UH93T5KD1v4FSFfW9m1URXIe10bgNb/CPTv0CDWuMjsgjdWB7hZyAL1tJxwZ4VjaGZH@TMqtG0@IhoMIQX7Y96BctRIwiLhrjWGAAO1@EihC2H@jLrQLA07XNrU3pJrIDBoOw@auzdWGjni3orX9qA6A3gPOgW20oWEn0Z3J7AwQQj3P5@eHqJUZxNOqEo1q7sojdCxtw0H@dSzS2keW30P2gmaFQwmvC1xFlR10A5O4dsDa0OefA6fNsTXkOjzUoxOM8szwFRW1xh2udaGyhxoDEhXMAVB37rZhvGOC5oChfPDI9pxLy3MdZLK2B6ihwlewDKaQz2MvVKOdnYPi08X8nYccODbjrcd4G8c6zdy232Z5x7Xdc5etAABWTU3jFfvAaQMJoPMNYXjJfOsDMWjn3HUmU3XQxO7eRx1R31gNtW8DIfMEr70HWcPmZzoCWJDnk4Nv9qCH0NcLBaA/eCvQJ8xkDMt0HtGzzSIAMeFqY73BkvzGHPQmiekgrB98FAn1yTV5w@TjegM6VKBKtPAPFDXeyLkPtPMgqBO45uV9jzQknMqIjzISuQdlENqpyA5vNpDD1JQ3@gasSCCdKfCofPdBdp72RqZktnsuk89AwyjWWL5jXuZR4Mgg6HqgKucgKdMjZSyMJiaApaE7Aq2uY9pW3xoe0HSX7aDqEnXLQSjOuUUIjixzKInxRiRecUoqkrXOOYffG2OH5EsmPdnLw6d7zaOd02dVOT/yvbxttaAGd8xmHxRP2/RlNv1JsWMTkIn4Hy7sY9cdVnlxXdjszk8K4wTRnz9tPj94crxz/DUngtD4Vn9kG0hKeXkKAKOfUHDQqmLzgF3P7YcauS8KYnkVWW8mZuxxeCpC1zB0JObrY/4b6N/HOXitLZ232yzn8tfQUwBuIiDOy1Mfdp7JICTN04eeArJEKHGuXvNagecWeoaz9In56wjdvPDFkQTma71wg8h9Z@QPYjm71nXyvxx2u9hrh95F8r7IYVW3I@9V8uaz/Mn5dcGWmaC5wCG@NcLHVwfm4psJmgsc4lvn@HBVYT66qZB5oCGyDUKGqxBzcU0FzAEMMW0SpvjKRRRWorBFyxYirbnBCyOFuLcINy5tRKhooUN4BYBFXjv6fNnBb@IcaVRHinoiFIP4YgXLdWBwso0gWF8@4jIGeIEW5w862nA8jFCsxlHkQOfgixhhOK8Iut00mtAqI2oDn1gQy9kgwPSNKPJ6GNmdiupakXcIzsu1aDdBBIxiTTrwiQeFkXgRBqsl8UZR5CXouYNJrC1fFznz@5YQJ7HWtcrZTXIItSMvEci5PQhWTEiZ5gLuFLrU5y4oQs8tn9Yk4xJPChX2M0kORh0J9VqOQorR7B/LXc6ftpTjiEgWg7i8cHGwG7maBU1fRywhiv6FPRuzCzoj/SRAZ4iaDeF9QL/VpZ85AGUxIwbdHS7xIFe@wFl9nLRzQYM3rwiMxvaEDLhlOUb@mB44yp9HT3K@IkFMy@yOQLnNw@AL3XeA5bZKBNlttaxFoMAXJD14zgHzRq15bINW2JuZ0mIJxg9H3tA2O@L5n37cgQKYLZ6eMSGFPnQ0gW9UN7oLS0tExRf6mV@yBPN@ZFsGsYFcd6FsG7iKYNihYz5q1ExYLtczvD7qzaJwoXLiD7SaW@oZp9wz7VHHDJ7zEyEWJyfOeGzH6lOO4IkDPxrmLog@Ne3H49PQyXaNDmHhAxzLjEqbl4s55qp@TIMGGXMPOoPZORYthw17o@GI/@IK2F3lag3wO58r5WQlK6wbLd3Mu77Rssxb6oFnXIw6bm5wcU6ZRtI2FtV23ohwMinXtY0L7myicz4DeBY96/zc9ILnIrCrHujsNNjIX9HjlqoSaEyMdGDjNpyezX8XgQQ7SELHYj5ZNv18SoWkKtKGVoOsxWXuXIxN1hRjbaM1wUFX79NrFiZIqigInmo7kymsYt8ZrmlEC@qDweL42OFS/K2t@bH5AjtnybyhSJ4vrOf4hBPlWSy139Hqoeey@oadK3ZizoVCPJjMjFxzQGkEnmvbhg@VaSiKw7yE4qOf2yo4dkZtrFaR65bqHZETLG0tWiWJ4gxAw7Atf8BbnHhZJE2n55cjNLjTgX6iqPg2y98OKbl@Lxe65gsEtz3ElYoF9e0eAo4vEuAyTKwCae4i3rXdK/wuVDF67qXJf@d3eh/mUnUPUZWzqWZY7TnRO@27qiuuddPPfC5ezKVq2Lbn@osZ@aSaf98K7Vu268N4G39vYwRozr7Pf@dX5TjPLMPJ0cRx3D0/miBqwDQxUbagJA373LU3Sud5A34WFvfI66L4F8/7ir1QbOn63WIr0I5cRxfPhfL@Iu9d3FUTaHbZw1WomPOWznae7BKrF4szCGMIXFqen7n9Qoliank@@bGoALx278qYBM/foktZxN2gSxlMSLcG5Q8jbJXAMfS4vv3bpLZ2e2qd@wmkGbSbd2UiVrgXtgnimX5nipQVC/onxtALhfuLp649MkfmXC3vsPXexK2BfJoWdyQYts2XN08PDj@RqILIxrKYJswD83CSMIT6IEaO96IaO298u1XAGLYFjfxOFWeuvBuAQj7AwfYROI7QMRvx3BkNEoUb493xyDm@nXO9QdCy3U6CSAz5VIlUuluRSujsvknfRfr9Xt@F8bHbB4XBuUf5C6Q0o8F/E4jJJ1IzEhMfc5MPl6pBoQXFA0rUuvBzOOd9P6FTXDSoJ@CtLRi2OeZwgr@LOD1PiLZc1/6UkgFZ2rFoC7Cdw22jd5XQjJIjdi2waPrCx6mQVnfRxAXvZ8QIE7iHo@nhLePn@DTTLUPCmSnzW3qr2AT6XYNM6KlpZsj32oF7UYU8xkatayVt89bqyHVQt2XaBn@MN9Zuw7elrd6KL9Q6hHJLCy64SMOXZaJ1rdSU6BlMgFlWBwYoPbNv0ustmr3ReT/yg8dCoLGL3znBWp4WGRbEG1jQ1h38TSwBxbShoevAkGpoeOcmjklsXJsUvovka7B2MZe5B33j3OQnBG4THdHUBG5n4yO5yDl/kqLMd5i0IRpfgL@9KkDDuTAnfvCci/DFpA3lOerfim1eG2/jDOidjVrLz12yuUPdc3puz@mZPY8aR/i2qHlAjRzysx23ZQLo7xn@Be7fI3kUjeV6fpy7tmvb9@EuykMuHV13/uTsHu6970DUT8I7MVoQIB53zuNBl01Mor57UdvpmSPomXx36A7MHL0tArVxxof/zp9vPjhM@@yNZXodvvkAp/@ModWyTXZlAQnv/fiK9/zZpJbtGrhF9BblHTgTPO8zP9V2vTsnP84NdzgY0KM5sEc@/dA8b647fwKzzPaJ0vtUBmvI933wKmueu612z7qLpJZpDB3rIh9M5PDXW8elQhhTzi2We4remm0Br7yJhpWgGg8/wcfBov4vtjwzN/e7I8@b3C0Ykqv54XwrXyVAx6L0xcLrnGDq8nFjU7CB55alCrFOu7A2kQKNynLOLIBWoi@c/0ns4RLSixYMFyg9U/kmYmJrZJ8yfykW@mkmz4ptVgD/eZMXiwThMyHfYFSoPBud@@rdFbfXAZ0Kf@Yi3DnHw058Ncm33avYbDM0fcMRj7m9criieNvCyPqtKyPz2KzlxdpmzhwtnO@yrYHPf1muW5xL3uxi/SzUZP7oVxRZx@zy37s0vb7r4cZ2UClybc/02zgNjtKYS0kughz3HKRyzmYRcAA7l/zZvQHzdJVkj5f76qV5buBGt@cW7nmz/dlOEDBPbxO4D@IfjQzf@tHIHZpzcU5vF7gPyhfGudV@liiBAGHAXbErij8SjQK9Zgviqmf5tL84cMxvSLyK0cr7bOD0THt4zu32iZGYniS2ebLcAQu2g4YOnOvHcGNuWkktVCy6LxR81pAmUMVzbj7nb624bVbhatQfjHzxmJ96H08LxOeR@xfk719ZIBVz34IQZj3DHs6fa45NpoJ@JXrGyLlI6/7Gst1z9k2pwEAdA4GHSviCivUE@ukjYwgtwJmtrHyzwTGdYgvPO/hZsU0P/CxPHLbyteBEY4q2NNLph2A3PEvhmYwRSvWh62mM4BTFyGRUVeKRcF783AGwAIrOlOF5E35czWe25Q8J1uqyep0tX4/LhbJ@w6pMLsus0eBY8UOnH/bGAzoQdsyj15eNRnU5ncull9NnTpkV0iG4aUN9mAtuJGC7Fj04vRELmGPwjavoDnJc4edp/B6dVQNdqAM61SuHpjpQP@OnQviRo1NckP@Pf9ERR/hg4OWDMgLyGBiCJ1jdvtlzrx7xdEXqO4OBgUcAEQc0X5sfSMnt7jCoV6B88ZN77hV7tX9aEueBxHFZeDninXNIBS9cHP7jbt4hLzxOTbgzUyQcxgoy1XbtUd8Bdbcz7PkaO7Foo@7Ii3bcgQvBnKGHOn8nyw5Yx8RlT9p/TcNc23Uv6CAFUvIf/4KfgqJd2GJ3bJA8nX6MpYibrXU6etRuuyOgOkDywfRcAaIgk6Exj3ACCbp8k/uruDeZjmdBjcwFh5MoGX5CaXfnhOX2WBpPAuOZh4rVVZZ3jj9/XS80qt@xft78Tz/Oq9eCcfJnua0NX86yAKRygxUrHrwOwVFomsnLY5knGG5Rt8QW9SteHsAig1cy3KUe1DHXHYhWQwdM6TxlWBuFmQIF3VTOwSmlPp1NpQprXtEpJdoa6qCQw0Ofjg8NDF5VQs1bXXVZGfF5jtzJkK1DgnjSywAXP81Km7bxxA1GWR6zj6yHlSzXxo3E8MYZaeMhr371SbAPZjW@Wyn/1GyNaIn@sqgVV6uUneVmdbtGLs/suHjYsv72bFws5M7Gm3uNvB8w9exs/Fmh@BVw3YUh2PLDPLa8vZdPr5e1WuHjR9@YMFm@SVf4jioQE8vXRwdHeyenO6evTqAUbgLxs@96fSOSNViLaGtwz7XpGCvwxbNM/xPkT/gG4IrClg22jeYVVFWK73olUMFrOScvc2dMNCVi3xF9XnzfjIXPAgiZ1rVYUKMOQDnGMoTKhlzDzI8GeBiXibjiQCHVMgtlPDagkDG4b22OLCVWyawKzMoBs@7JKrY4s4@43304dieW29n2aC4IcixMrx6G8yzOZcHN30u@B9BR/u755lhuzzfB3JJvAA19gzj7OwfPXx3vJaNBHaMnSd3q1rrY7s2FM7Y0PkUSnKCkkzEiIs4RVWUmUwT@Kjozsp3RModXJmRLCMd2n0emGkr0y1JUMYEzVTRA0qhwXigKUYA6SAWzNbUbvWuNYyQGfXQM3TXPYigE9uUQdUC4JgvMKTInoeEnyAZiFewKmt4RCXEhr9N@XP3JBi0Os4Z9NKibFGtBVxX2Oj6D/1ivFLiKDTZmojvTGyzHivC1TRhq9UJYtcL7KLbMGSEvc9rlkF40ZQA0dd4bNDSjHVRiwz300rYxwHPTAvolDIfK7NuRS6d7AmES6hdXqPgb3GoHFW3bwNzQqSFniGegg36L8B3sn1RRO@OqGcn3eJ0bOdhRAVDMhsbeGHR6qGxdkvX8ND5nuSsOfgddJc3d@eKgZ6gl@OzS8mluDwuhizqODZIScyMyjuZn6FwX27F90Ek60H1zYy2knGi0s5dv7805TE5BndRClTHLZAlh/ersQWDoSq/a0K2@45GXCY4w@zGc6e2lXA44d245zHcsGHENyzgFSZMGZTb0RrhQXkvPRAlIKJMr1xv27RjgHJMIZ2b@h3/6p9wMwtkQ3H8g3OPCE3j7I/HWBfc/CUJ0Hd7@WfhWhLef8re3eSyy2bPfM3RiOxcZ4/SFJYil9/rgiPk094nl0zfGMdaj1MB6ZDnAA6sPBX1J5YbgPIWoWCI8Sv01FDvUFShzVFlQS6H0TK@h4Knecj6PGj0OyDTaLWuO@cQnHfL9doTGLUCxym@sb6zpeSAydxkgpJN257g9kyNU1TLIOenSGlTftdq4mZ7JftuwzepGhZd3ftl4uyq/CwldBliJK/91BnFw/30YA8JqIpqybGR0FaNi55TW0yinOi6vPqDhKeQAEBW9neCoEqiQrmAV1E3HHA9JC5oEg5oWmiDCCRqTmzgJEOUAEceNJhimm1i04RL3p8canRYvBvkNgp0gWFmeVwHrb9nZ8MxpCFMcDCrTL@dURwfcfzjHPgevWXj2cNYwhDJt1gFzwx6fOC5uzN0HaplSzBdX8/qGGquhskAF9GLz/QgoocGCAGib1nt34O/s7h18cXh0MmPggCDT02Bplq5tZ85yWrbeCB3pkO4kU5/s509ePNkPWBmnKlq2Roho7XqazHmpTVO6IPU3fKfrbNoUMJOQXrgvYlooyu3T1o5Z7FFoPga4y3fYzaSqqNc39cZ27cxJzST/cZ7Rl5S2gpULXGc@mXxJT5OJJB4E@3dP0RScrwVnN4pyZNIoPFXC3yPvxSYKQsNykZ2CYKewRCcIwwOEkrZgDzHkXcvzpOiQPicsoBdkTUCqjqRGCbalma0HcWqYyMusDTxxRCZk0iGfFwosmPkc0ifhzGeOyFhIyLMQ7jTAiE0/shwgjsz3gDrbaklX4nRncMAoPNmp@QPbGiqq5AiI6aNGs5D@rQfwQzCjWh@z8GyNj3rgWCOzLQrZt7lqSNx@AQvMDGTIUsHRCPh25A5YNDP21Axcx6AnsacjSKKNg6wvRn2A69Lj2MTewgTNKQeRgZ/pgJQ6ns0XnND6nXVlrGo9c9yxzqHHUdQsiKbPdD2ycWDgIX3QlVrzcoBTTYOeAXnAolndRhMBY3V7i16jDPKVE3Y139tpSIAMo7bUMp@NSL9yAnM0WPBlls6GnGmp2bTG@OhIWJqh5VOaXNLYbg83m9F0RrdrkRoWPznMO/Ou5fU1zBV0M7wKfY5bTeO15pPMTcQ4Y9QNzXI65ljBk73lBvIJ/NNXby7TqjxTxcnmhbBw0Jk2fhHIQmMohFJkOGJK3m1thXIuKRq2trSeL@EpLRhoQIonQ@85OEFFULp9Y8CUEVkP8ZnG6FU5U5ysP/RUlqthd33FHJbJ0DwFPCgAxiEI2iWXRce0FTS2peSrUEjo6zsdfHywBqyua1oD3JSIypZxjnIXtCmc3VMlGHdClDKhBf0C/spIETdsqAkDh8uUrEQH@AFqbjDJqfMeyRfgBeWa1R5Gp6VjAoZzdWurLEojKe23GNSL7TkCEdDOkeKB3g/8FedsgGsoowFq1zM7FsjLx1@ajmMCg6DO9NGOozGCSuap2cDEaDYyIkYppDiJz8TBHSA0aVxsL31tu6CuLecrNN1VuQG15t0Z6jVdodlM8v91XstXrpVluzrJg66p1pTlXlXPrK5kMsvOirLsoLb18CHOkt0sgzLX1GDQOQag3LKtVqA@g/JXXXYqy8a2stypFlcoBrzCsPcaInzn57XrZeMmv/wQlKUs@Hhc6CjLPtn9KGiafgP0YQtZzmehzlyjAQsyHIrJL1uZDNKgLTeRgO/yZycZ6jbPTvI0IVcR@n3@vC@a25QqFpbEjMFTzkDhXQ47rHXssMT@q2YAHJkWW50XtkD94wl/ibtUGS2um358QCUnQ@4vWIScRpkrhIzCDa8AA8cKMBFfs4aqgjD5zW9S@gZj8qONVcXNPFovVDLpdR2G3jBmTj0GPTy/Invy9dnT3CUzc@l611jXvm0cXRwdfaWeKWyLpVO7h7K@Jr9lW0V2v88mKy74sN/lk0qt5KVUfkV/uJnPv3v3DkYc8KnXtBqID/5R67l0o65sMlbb3FzJbpRWso/TzRhhqlIsqicsz84syxr4nQ583R5Z@VVS/PPoEaUFQ3r4Z9xPpC8cwQuCCN/Up8IZ6yl2tmkYK5m14mOnAqRt4WeV6eDE3xJ8dba@zvbw8zf/29/8/G9@Rn8/p@9fGeyCfYDPRZfhP7k/dGJuA92t7ge0iwJDiyrJhUE6vb6aPnmbZv@ffZaYXnu0@Z9/dvhtapiqFfNvPHgOU9@mNkop7gQHvK0Gb5epWmobwTZuUpN8tVoF5@Z//jcQv/YF4MGQyTb81NYDXBuTVC1XpSgfU7UNcOjFIqT7f/34x1KqNk59SOm6nprQXzNV0PFTeqg/ZAwceXmzJLvu44De0sY4/AR@eV0vnkXlGStuLNrQuwfpQLkyN5UEJXdYq5ioDeT4FDg0cbux9PjdU8ZM6GrxUy4/nmH486n3Yy0HH000gzG@5MZBFlKlarbJkw/rairmmMpw@MtE3sP3T4STUoE5x1zd6DbYOPY5S@mltcPH43t/WER0wMRUxLswcTbtF3A9fGFBo2efAielvqtWj4f496KFf0cn@Pfbijn2CD5L8Ef/8Alf8XeJfIQ3gcx@ln6H5iql6ql6o/GjHv15@PfMwb/Wt/j3/AP@/WiIf6dt/Dv@Ef4tyoyU2t7eTmUyx6Aaijp7n88r@GpaU7wFdRfR/b1@2NrhxuFjiaVyjUzu5qauvR1nKhXxD0pTJXzDD3cBWY2bXG77bS2TqRN59ZqgczvXqAGtnGT6ebsNiDPb9e1trVmr1XKNt7X6djKSiPf4cQbb6WOIWGvU61LqGsuiij8r@NP28bcoy3l6xc4CeuctcDFy0kN4MLLDju9S6t32OyXzKPOoYBcuC/qFfvHCPYz@Dw/HEGCNC@9dr9Ar9PQOSERWMF8VJoXJuNB3D/UOOE34K/TBaRW648J5wSk4uj4ZJ1At/u8fusMXhy5gcyHmcFwYIuJCF57nh4cvAF8X0n4Pf1ahUBgDkePCJfwXbBTUZCSKnm@b6plUZ/I7E3p/TU9rhbS2kU5bjfWNwbdn1zfFjW/lbLp5Vk83Kqm8f3aW59oRK65VyETYzU2zuffyabOZx3q0vZx5nMk9hk@1ltkWj0epWuXRWTmH5cfrn9ZM5bcfndVWc@jeyEAhFcFvO5/5xE@EEp61pTMJBnxv3uD3zdXlFXeRg1xnb96EofiTRy9ykRd8ADQ/N37CwUDT/Af67xz@/@v/xSum1BsqY8r1zbZCHxX/VPX65vpG/NZURREvyjb8oQe8Y5Trmxo6CegaXHVFbag3N9wPfhV1myOsYRrbNYocAUKDTfFUz9IV0PCqy4pYKDs7GxcKaqUFPuH0uvGR1lzUCu1GWW7hOhmMBvQVlUDW1yqVNeHeLFUqJeHWNzYqlZUQqgAvwglApm@0K1jRKykVSeBjA0XPF3FWZQsGXPrq9vbGeq22sQ4vGyU1pxQwiGw0ps/Sg8HgLK3R9LpGx9Sq1R3PMyY0K7MG470zaF5p3KFS3VpHe7RbuuvltlbVtKq@1QXqosppkOvL6RTfocL00iZ53jRMP5Uiv1TK9NPLeTkFtdRn1zcp4hZbW1eV1sRU2dqGUspsib/qksq287UVJv7q9dXM2srmyuNGI1IDsFFXro2qflO9Nso4pL@ptIXNQtyxZjx8uLr18aNeKlTOpGbz6c7pThONv8sySswBY@hL8kHC9b2Bl67TBMz6VqOOxDfO0uly5TEvh9I6S6UrAi6XBknDSluUxxSM8qwu7lUdoyAW37K@Ulxdyq@PP9vYK4BW/HEFP/V6vVQsZVZAEq1sbTUaDfL9uERx6v1xt0Hmc6q5ur6x3sihuvF@3F0BYvXN1dSKNKDdPJsF1sEFUQ8ntJbAs2f4rIVr175p24GdyCvXsztXVscE7EfPd3b3TrPFbUBZ3N/ZzRZPXj1J6fi6Hr1T8Cq@H@/tPD18BRGOnu/tnOx9fvB679UR@PvQqQGz4NM/MsyR2TSvRqMrfG@a9Nm1fOP9e2MwaELdGoy7P/zyJz/88r/74Vc//eFXP/nhVz//9fc//wl8/wK@P@XPn/7rrXX8/fX3/@x//uHPfgWefwXf/wDff//r7//Fj/mX3v8avv9HzO@vxTcGx7/ASsD2R7/@/md//uvv/8kv4PsvxfcX098f/uTf8v//U/yh81c//Mlf4494@clPAeHf/eUv8f9nf/l3/@GX@P@//E9/95f//O/@6F@R40@54//@l/@a//7t7/3kb/@bP/7b3/t@we9Pbv39/h7@3/8D@NyfzvvguU@@PtXn@9@Knt@FG1EqVKl@/oc//Ivfh9r6J/ztH8Mb/IdBfxC@hCEZGn7lMpHnHzD2MQ8KTuHxxxAUUP6P6Ave7GMSG/kWAt9ff//Hf47eCdjfj2Mo6LOwywgcpvYHAPtnIWFx2D/44Zc//uHP/9sffvmnP/zyj1CI5da2sjvZnH7HCAYA1@8Bh4Ab94EDQOhctrfZEluSiuBY2saJBUnPvHsHLF0CFyjKK9L6KrxJeo3cOrohIow7VvjIN4PjefiOpbUteAMHeI3JAUEZCHqSYdVqNSONqxBGoPCKccasVsIxKur2VcCLkXicbLMEeiMbPyEsELOaOWbNleqYR8ygR40wMCQIvY5lvShnStWnkGB1/JQhLkSekd7B8121VqqOa4juOyIBcGSeQJIAVUXqxrXv4L1KOAFeGj/9DkgpVTOZWgl8qpRVSi3bpDT1dcoc5T3DKN/ozxjOdD16zNhnsl6S@RgLWMkENP5mIuhHNNPwCMLPMisiO/QfOOm7gvGhnMbEH@7Hwx@hN8UXAIA3l8M9S/DN5ZCaxxA85qgylCw8MhwDcC4jpmRCD@pZM1KGyjdDL5A@0HC/z3Yt9oLoMDvLy8vg2q7Jq/IhKOvMuyj7Q8PD6X/SWspM3tiS0Ru3i5jLR6TOrzxdgV8d/veWaBsnZ8eKtJzG7jvNgjRymVV3zU0R9UHWKC8rRHmG4KRU5M9VSFrDAd1vjamSQsaOVRoTmgPQWqQX/vkTd8yUQlaWs/rGFp8KFUPGr91yufqdvrYpwZPeR2hnWVj8hWLAu3c0bF3I0Np1bptaGjhBxdiQajWxDsV0qXaydwoRTg@ZXixoDNTA67XN4tr62npxdWNjfbOor21srW2sl1ZBQm0U1otFfWttbau0tXkDBD2Gdp4tr7TWt2v/aObzX/2jeZ/5vviRal@xscaOjn6Uu5Fq41wuXySSq/r6ZmVSBULIS6qR9sR10Ml1zvcZFo90RtuYrnF3DZAmXeewqj6AD5MeSOwBeMEHMOMsPBNLwweHFbFGhlbs@TqZrK9DZVClM6gMHJs0iH8kLLiHIG0e6ty5vhE5C@iUTvEEx0tIAMrBYc9xg@HQZacu38j2xGwvgNjt8Rubdj0X9M3fHuaJ4VzwoKcWWodrD8OgZwaaf/H71rC3AOLVoI/H3UzvHwzDXr8FBOJEIQd4Aj@e7brzADbZq6MFuXwRnvTCJTc66gXgxwefPzuNPU/3dnafSRvsyeHLp1OPdQG0zp7v7Z@Gr5s8NIi6HqL4eu/58@lX8cAxwxJb38xmQfDBDz6z9KGntvw2ANG1xT2iqRWyerY5Ma9zuZuWiba9T7j18iGuoHep4tuur6fT52YfOjJoqjrUZtzMeu7aMEpaLuwWcHEg/xFHOU2zuD5hyyD32vYWjBjZ9nptIyWvy6VqsbRRgDFgNUMm1ruOwtRKagOHhPWtRnXMVlmp3hikfOkFbtfa0vlRAsuXnsHYpI/mpfH48lDyzA6MU64cOiXRwqtcRgO20BMe6IVOzzrvgQC8ckMAH@pzyzAYfD/1AzjM@Gd4u8eQp0F@MyH2LLh0Fc7qhNM1LJy3EWLhDe7jpTM8weIwdTJ@WTpFcUw3/DA8hNVCo/h0mBT6eX46lEzYmyCctyQJF8SsLitIGk1zFbdK66Wt1WIpW9oqra3DkHE9qxez@mZpcwtqS0Ev6Rul9S09W1rbWl0D0Qyh61ubUgrEl9XN56Hn0WWZnpbTRmOV22j109V6NSkFJY@NiY3xTrSUEXqMSkxeLZ0VGESUJdzPujKuynhnYAFv5NNlSTZYm6X293cL@/uy/ARfcE5vtyDLHXxZLxUKm09k2aSQXeg@ihCph297G6jByrKFL7s7@/uI4T2@FEuIQ5YveAh/sYOXTQBz8GV1lVRgWf42RFcA5C6nqESxhvylUHiyK8sjTh4e1AO4Hf62RsTu4QsGYKR9HrILYbL8eRCpAGyQjzmcSOpZkN@dHVk@4C87O4jiC8r8Os/Ul/iyQx@I5MEb1HxZPgfHuQdDeVlugRPrvyy3wdWeGODXBxcev3OGhixPeD4wJ7I8JmijfSGDZif8IR2g59kzozfsmOf8M/H4sw1BBxBkjUd7@63PP2@dn7e8yc7e58cU9MUXz4z3k5HXOm@JiK0mfFyMBUEX/cn0x8SgZtOw5wd9CUHOVFBz0jSJwqbxLVAmPueYUL/5BQZ9AUHzVoAEQvj0AbiFnyd9eD4xWjwo@FAQPcetllzBKotNp6tQxTWy9Ggx9RplomI8AlV9TS6jdHW7oGCNSmpu/dGoJG9syuUVeMqP5FVwjpVCusCYnD6TZRWk4iN5c10upx89yqUf6o@YvLkll@XNTVmt3KBgVtTrrjLOjqsF8Mjnt7EdY8uDJ@gsQuE4NcdD7ZmJuy/audybxGd7@w3A4UlzPBD3ctRnT9gViQ7cHh/sJm5Wn4CcKFQcPIps4uvyODWWah1jaMDQ48n1qFwWsDeV82odEXzEn@2c/Kb2Rm6weLrrmwWg6pXTLm5ub9c/NkDvquqVSQq6kmKpMk7RCYjNtYoCar5a9c1vufb10cY5sqVmtcD1sGV/1K8Xljb07HWuySe3bmzDHy7rm8VyfbRcz@mNpaXCx/Nt@Zua3EAaUEejv/hsHki1CvgFfONyMNW13kE4K@f4fQl6aUPVcGd30@02ySY6excTdxhxUBWlKzMFLzTh20iUdHqzmE6r6QoAL4G3KDaqFkG5yiBSoVy3iqADVjxzOAKNo1C5CWgJk@H654YupW6kDprFXNuSUtfSzfXNdi3o0L9kk4mRyQWvDxk7z8BQJE@rBrjesESunFZ7zHaqO@fHOxUBurNLAwaoOmf8xFEuv/SpaxOZ7dpb/jyr4VodpCMR@Xz9Lr@dqeVrtdqZJMtySg6nlkvrMMzAsfh3KZouZrvX3ZFDJ5vLL5BhRpkrJfWG@t1Ly74ureZqtC1GgYp/k8ps53HRS6vliVvtQ1oSllKOK5w4cTmEdqCApr0u45jGZIOTrbebb0tvX7w6fHW4zx4XyqVyibOC1ugfZ7N6Wk8Dax9D92Yd70mpwUd3Xf/O@aKSKg/Sq2vp1YQudVYVB24VrAlKHafi66uNRh3GKw0V3qrV4iN9vZRZK@ubaqqGB/@Km6kaOaB95VZTDT6nraxtMhVeaIq4qKdqeeGvb@pqys@lxGz45jpoS6nSi3cfYawpLly0iuTK5wVVyzfbN/Bfu6nDcOyGRmU39I8/efi54QDwj@DhC39EnxhcHCYKb3yX2@b/2/Sze8hpljeA46l31RoU7Nvm22ZKSm2la5l8Gq/@FR8xzkHNZ8WhP9Nfwb@3kccKKGsr4Ru8bq@w9ZrOmLmSz@fP1B8VQXHZ2toobaSk30D2b9n/DKHhjrmuCSMLEHxztszteNYLA7cTOuG2OXC8GH3Aq24eB3dkBjoOQyUHt7qilhP3E4pPzIuulk36Tfw8nphCX0lCl0WXZbMu1SUUWEM65MNWUPzgaW5VupYeAK5Re0iHreCnIkkP8IQdvioBXJY99IcqnqooqNKDB0K@@EPNHzYROUYSnjm9It1IyB6j0/EZXTaFqzj8CLiBx4XcAbcPZ08Yj@TTfUBcYQuvjIgRvMK6nArIzQqjFIlyzBxP/gEHa426SMr@wfM9iAOdQJc2r4nYstfCm9woe0tdlYViEniA9xFVBacIHAEBHXjy/ljt4znzNrVLlmE6hndpExxAZZmeJUqyrCsi1vG1AdERfbcNwx9AzFNXeA7YSlMkK/Ig6KFMAAsxdyTq6aYg77ydFaWHxtVxcfE6OKSnYCjbZkU1dlCRcEFh8NuXKWK73xHXSlUjNhM2vZGFoq3w04hKCCd8IkbdSCvDbL/Ci2pQkb5U2qA/uJ5S@a7/8GH77aDeb1TUfnWIz0ymDz3QhWJxkJVhtV@F6jGoW43KsJ7JWI1qX/1SwXe8/A27K6H8@KrIG@TcqQItuKnQV7Mf6k7uO6eR3a87GSB5lF35pvoha1QLqL9kraqetbPfgibA8wFpDqsfMk7F2IYvbgRNHBSF3jZjVBJeGOVCsasf6kYDFSIbImYy@5AZoNOv25lMQ4XEbQicjVixHz40MnZtXLFzORWh3q4@2q8PwdHIVPG9rBjb40cf6iOIX1bgWYVkbBWIh3iC1zch7UBfBXjMyzQindNI@toYyOtXqyvfPFr5ZqW6tPShPs71G1nO/nIhqg1I/BiJr8SO4ior36hsiiW0SKzIn1nlz7QVPE9pZTLA5OwgFpNTuPINhAwymYDqG5SXp/FxJNYwcXaPn5Skaxto/ZY0IhpB8punUFzs@G3LEuDckMLAQrMAeMlslq5sMwgCw8Ql1Rh4Nn70SAqSFie2IGUULjBiNXDgTleVenQQAG8X5RZF7pKv88RwIHPDASddHwZD29WNWHMl0UQNzvfadQRBMXBduKlwicXP6YGwIekBMCQ9EC6HUgSZJOSEgKyKQCitoIAgFsqJLjdSRnaaUD7hfXthywcRwsmAxjyHDCv7vkqyCeqTBS5mbVN64ICmIj2ATCANmAerwWogyNjDh0y8boN@XdzEvgDBEO59RkegGUoh8XtQCjiQyvdQR1EeUiJA2wMMwRPYiYTWfreEhFEFBSJk3me5bQWNbCsoI8fntkiQbyonA8viwYP3meqaIAj@SfWG@BB285uU6O7LbPfwxdGr073jFzsn8AvDtVL8VsbgwuSZ61IHeA1qy3LoLGXbONbNr79oM6bgUATvYMD70Dvsi1fPWbH48mkWjSMD61N83hw61HKIyfTphhpfc73z/JV1YeX3ElZM8epqOrbpl@mmYrHx0SQ7B3QFemghJTKQ4uMkGnTmwqpr4oBK3/R9cQtsDlrXyAOlmMzqka2YPpo8gVYobo2lIyOJ0@@4ZQB7deZ61rlF16T3OIJEfLr@bcijU/uQ8LZXGjpCjZa2SoVCmRWy6NADRzFwrAaOtcCxHjg2Asdm4CgFji3h0APMOscM48vV1Y3IuRk5S5FzK3SuFSJnhGGtGDlXI@da5FyPnFFqa2FqGyXCy1IBN6npmh6G6WulIIxG5UPyXAc0@rTnGhBanIGE6GsznpBeKem5uVUQCR3kDxGoWNyI3kH6BLBVhVOV5XRkecr8TXhCXyXxYRtV2D3PA6m0N8brraHSqWWGRg4kCXeytG3TAGXAHIKWUt2H@m@qZeqDht6kHFl4QAxVPXyH6Hg5IMTR6YZ2Xn3mBBfnBXNsxbnYxLmwkDExWxeCSE5lOdHTcoxrCb841iUUsMjRBRBFDoFlkDSNEaR56o3mJrl6e5IJhHOTnCGK412fFwt5oxDyahCV@n/CVg3S43qKSaUNagDGhEKnOjBVoGgaq3qtl@Vff/@L/5X9@vuf/Yr98Ge/@n/@/f@A7n@LP/8ObUAUQ4Cf/ozR9gP4@eeMNhfQFokoEsGvluUffvFLeP3v/xX74Sc/40F//Odydi1EBCHoFcX8@T/Gn9/Hn/9dzq6HgD//Qw6IUeTsjZRQrRSA@ulfMQapIZYQ2S/@gjE5AwqGImpenbfxRswMDkcQsqFOrsZ0OP/FW42BxwU1IwNe8aZHbxksADWG3DPQVlzU9kCd4TN/KKXbRruHpiWEl@uj/tNGFcb1tXOob1cdUHrE9EIacv97rMzSGYTBaRK0BFblMlzkX@RbjkIRNiPngTq82FOgojufQ0pgeBucvASnhsMWGpHqvI4I/r40oZsIOhA5qFl0h60k0gpi49xKii990KXGwVAXKy12Q9ySFi00ScL8gB5LMCFupooNUpn2gSFjZBQnHpU8zP4AjbpUI34jY/GFuJCdRheVnGg2e4f7Uw0GPy1QMS/iEilMqMpk@Q5Y5LSAV1HjWk3Cc3oFQL1QXm0kzOvMA5a/@uorWYr5FbAOeR2FMMQyxUVGGKQng4qxoGIsyOoKnCRr1ovFKRqo40C5mLQtxaPFRFQyWlS5sOUE5YBkwFgQrwKX5WzXHvm96ixqkshJYTeLPIZSb1RFOzlzSObUmKzORACcyTjV6bKcj7owAzNbUPNjIrcTPonSWowpESfWKIh70jSXwpLTt@aVXDLBW1Drjcw9EyoWfseEcvdMaGP97oSmixXjJtAv5u/dYicQE6GEj5Dxhp9KdFDYNf4Cql4kjpBij5yKCkOeHTHkaV25TAmGH@fWsDdq0TAG/PPBrQj5lu228n0c5Xh4A0p4VwIOYtBaEp8eeDxwYcjhohYcDJUMh70S4Mlz8XSd9rnjeqYft1skbth20mhOqu2eO9CrZfF2BuvCFPesm8IWcrJfCXs2oYWiDWwY@iBqzijUPJtNy7GGzSYon3ZXjRiIr1obj4SnpTZEBFcsvhKqtocDxcXbZYbq3ThJ3@XRTq32hXI4EIFpSGSHwYCubdow@GI9vJQ@uGEcs8ivqQeNtDVUyBJ0z@2756bjoiUtjD2F/iDCjQQZgwHRkmVGlrVjFIlBtNLOGqqI@uUnR2VfFhVDDeMXkwgSzMgyb5rHyFlvTnLNhcnxaEF6J59O70mc3pPb6e1anj@cppk8cbYHn5@W9KoSYQDAiIzVu8nICsOVM@QkSAm9fdSLKMK9SezQ3qUOUroDoDsCXOtC/ciGbz4d/haEv17E/9sLMIi@d9/iI2X2ZALypr@Huh8N0fxgjVoB8ANVDbc2xpMLq/bTe6YlBjo0wssymQSXg5YFoGEOBqYTXSAfIL6jzuP@opl6T5uOqjxwDk3eZZZdFBcX0dNmx7SNidlRBGQ2hjfI8bFpdEhe3S/jKOhI6MEYgCYyC1k9oYoh0zlQeUGVMbKXqrq4WnEQK6w9tBhHFB4s5h9N3E2LZpwErfI1ENcDCZoii7BkwHcwGUy4USybTOUFcpT3P7wkX7rCFt@tDAE@iIX@bJSsepv4PFbCLN2jRwhhtWSWyfZC0G25oI3PlOGnsejunNIsQxipGpRyQjtZVOLWbSUeqxVBneRayf2q5F2V7t51LlbVOLJIhO1@Whcyg3nXsO12W4lj5D63lpjrzMgE9MMSc50FvUpzjkANY5KkG@KVuVWuX6iSBc4DeF7C8zU8ESGMQZu8QgV5Q702mPKikL4xiGktwqfeRl00xkU1vo4Yg5ICN07k3oRpthem2Z5Js51IM2wBySRjQFI7kaQoBSye24rANrvDBdIZg3DkDo/bxDZ8HNfwcO31Om2ly1aWpS/TZRDIaTNd3lNAKKc76fJTcvjp8gk5LtLlL8ERta30x3Q5aBYI4MErOR6jvxDh@N5Ol3cV9UYaojnsIF0tXQ7LFGAe8VfiyA2fXm2JVX83nFU1zSxXKrMMa4wPDxezVW9k6VuAf273lttnh8ClKiuuEDAOQBKdRqzH4OlAtxHY2JrTksvB1JSY34jmUCA8U41NqmAtGZE8SqfSSWHECcNQmnyEJxCIcrM8nyKmz4zM7iJHpI4GwrCQk@kT9zTSBzoKhdcBOD6JY0fxg/JKouAFeD86MfIiOmfICZIjinAzgDqHLGTqu/QtmcKynrLYzUs/XkKzcwRYiLkAhJcSoY3JdNDhUDelxAbuIFlJKBRX@6x4HPyIRom1dyoaSQXRMhcEk7fIGQqGeONXb8tOLB6SlhBBGFgvNHgrC/sFksUYFMm6mKbKGx@QEJM50MLN9oWJ1fapcBIcFzdZ6isWdUNBXJ4kSa6kmITIGp7AHhlDnnq0LoPnsj9t@BrEHOO1MwoiiMUMU@Hy1f0E/d3l@nugUAdMmEpgnmI9vyudVa9v7WWnKLejZGcLEAOz7Kk6VzkKU4hYDqODmGZ@W12bUfFHTqDk80RD7FPafsC2cExwB9@mxxYcF2oJ3mXS8wInZi@Kixk1q5HYl1qgtGiYksDDMx5SGmXtdlp5xucVMYZgHw2PTy5gL1nA8cJDfJQBb4rlvJXj6SxapwjbNhlHi1Yu@KqDi7vEQmPzMU8Q97R/LdyiBR6HzeOnhy@ffw2d7ubmpjq7FIGtFuJG/bh06zJBOGwpZtFqKh6vo70TPdcbLp058uyWMvIAZcCgdRte/UQbV4Usi8nzqbYL8ThsjKMC10XUDIyEVEJVx8Au2xJ85bd2KiuGQBKot8DvLI3WcNUIawcu6DSb1H01aYN3syl6MSyacBnpNykmTOpJqeQeJtKz/BmLfTjsH/XphFMw7SZs8fHdJ2gf62AYxA5jjZyhFWxxwFkhOj4ZrOArqzrOSRx0Qx@iA7diKMU1HLgW11V8UCyExulO2lAp0lni6g3aFvUHrkMG28kkKSnreI2OH0y4Etkj58qgzR88FbK@EaOIb8MKVsNch98p4/O4eG6TJo4D3mSZea7ROk9xCwYaF9aAm9ION3z4KkUigmlnFvC4ZZt9IOkEauycOeQXFlSa3r51fg7VJy8uoOXbWk4NiJpzu7ndwIZiir02bCu8sEPsBKP7dsTsL7BTSRjB9FlxA3SorSxwNvoCY3FzDENDlwXamkVQ8N2ExyZ3lrKxuEvKRJ19rupLShNL9CPvFzy8ZPbScGL8pc/H@ES0WKKkVh9bpwTmOsJ2XhqN54X2FyVha7hKy5QablEbKHJKDgwzolMaeCaK65zO908YdjuwGKmgrdKy9MAhCYRbwVibb7IBTddB7Y3W2dRwb6rDPmOrRYkuH3JpllnYvJUe8CW@BHYIg6iYD77NT0ga@bOO/BmuKkoPUigUefXD@EHtRjddMBFVb7Yk0OF@V7GEyZtF8LIee8HWwa8LgqzjaGQDKJxDyZIiZwBtRlZljjqMPx1dLJM84CJ6FlMWV@oeCFYDlt988v5t0/McApMuXajIfRetk/K9x5VbdgPTdmDcc5jYDIxEx3d3dsWmN36jYlZ@5dM1CJQIdTgaWutFeV@ZFvg5PdjjSQ/cXM1W6PRxN9E7yR5GDslYspzbCKBuiCo6iinaM/aZX4Yv0JANUAKbaJuDQrxR76SNOIKbr8lUV6MS64cUPU4NEtj1QR51gZ9Zma4OeQgRqV@GTlKdp2sVKon4QJw/cGj7t5zTZIoqtiojpiQKXproH26YlWiXfCD3brlewcjrpcLGFm26Zk52mO3XtxrZlXZVZubQMpy@P/KuOhfnbu8SNAw2eN8atycfvmVsfY3h8ZLiQ26oQN@o4okOhW2ibUm2VaCzHYLAR2R04UxmjE76ooWFNGPhIaDKEp7zh08Wf8pyZaaWspV@UAv5zut@faNRdaqFSr/uNCpOJqMOM9VhRs8o6PFQVysgqPlcTX3YoK2U@RX2ItjviNZ5cULW7bIj12n33LTP6Mrv@EIgnbYKGlDfGMTb0yUMVVwv7tPF@mT0Ew1x1osuyZyKabkB3HAyMFGMhltFbRfqL/48GG2sVWbDMYcPHuC@5opQaOMZuJYGo5ZttUE8ET9RL8E9juWy2KnfZlhvQXahn8U9OS3QgSkYXAlC2@5gIiJbHKQZ5GU7hrKmYNenZu8DGUC1oE428aoID8A4CGdvApwBaurBVE4Vup@bTtg74eEKtYJbz9lSEBYcw0B4rDd0GKIJOiMdnYDHNhOgtDGZqWIbMPnWLdyJQPpdLc2DHrwf9QekHmicXsERvBWuOTAsL4yp@SO8/VJhOjLDCojGEkDHDZ6VuwRtNF40QVngbAStiGN@EN8RWfsGgtsG3p4MshFXhBBfx6U4D/h9hQp0mHy2i5Mh4lI2VFHUwDg0xJYepMuMJicq4EXdTyUW@h5CMa8LgvsQ3DeGvQXBPcQ98hcFexCMtxguCLYgmG9UmR/uQjhXxBYADHHqDaprc@g2h4ZlK3yXNe7PvuECW2GZTMDYsAowXjC8PJLxmdivzpZ46fDKlqhe0D6pWnEArNKKaDz4HtUWCkWrHAqvF7E0OU/YNbszMTFjBSxuUkogdjF9dSWBn8UIgPYHopTNhgeJ89IOM5qoPxq/0gqCt0Hmf/x4G2WiIibrn94Iah8vIZwcjeWQcyvCw@9Fi8qVR/ogIs2PI/bzx6VboLlG@QgaZTESIbxtRe26a4FuCVFV1HIibxyHquxR5FP3G6wcSo@Ij7xZ3M3H4kztwWEqtcgsa0XO9v25amC9h5gG9MitSFjg4S2jMsNOP4TOJaFrAB1yc6qetRN1RrTST83s/XKTAvqoURNvKlzQtkE1rAkC55Bn8HKNywSObDld5v54l5WVRGYtQMYPOTYBwXAbaMCeLRDjQZ9oORrfKARyvlBcy9K8Pwe5idgUCKv78OnvoXEh40SXPcL7L5Iiic1hzQx4mG/kV226yU1lj0v6@Zmr851m6UdppJHN1ieqdY@glyyzAgtP01TYzd1y6LfjzHVUfAl9x1cWy4qg0IOaeJ8qeLOA0XdWsmQWig2W4DiSQJLhji6JTobO75Si9Y5m4BPMhfG2vVADQ6oqyXCkmSMMAkBRjsfKCp2rFolOcSS2OQyUm2ykheGtWrxWgMpekeLiHIdz@9R5x33D8zzEkXgIbi9EDdMLKLO6gW4LanAQT2s3sZg5k5Gf0KbPXbejBAqTUBgIQ7BtGoCy/IxRqFZx9TJKHpITSi87F1uvg363Aj5Lwov6lQrd5x7oZ0jEyjk1mwo2m5h@Y/l06RuFY28ESQVLQjiXxKUPK0/7I3SoAj2YGymQ@HhQjI4TCzlPPXFCPMi7hoPzdmQzjIbW2zL6hwWBMDUYaEeHjqkMbubMMvCD1eLI8XV86GJVLA114rDQxagdhukhNdvbMiYTGaT4TWopP/K9fMty8qZzyfDedykVTm@V8VbPXAlnb/FuTiFNaLKcJoSgmkBJYWqaY14p4V2fOPcg8YOCNIGko8kImu7CSbcOaP18G/3A9cf0O4HBQkEbDYYuhYiE6EAh@2h9jA65F2hpV4wYBDnbhCeCUXDRh/tO@LxVTucKko4GP9QYijrGJIErn8kylh8SKqb96g3J10yj3UMisO595MMpKC6qyTeSHxQ9HoBDVuCKIjhtvvV3QPN4mARpJ/6E3iH7@K6jg/vQTCTWezFOkWi@FkPwzm2s5Dgth/G3gQGc8Q9OTp/uHR9rfDaOz9/gXZsTPs2M@zboFKG4vFvMsuISAp7h5IXyADOLuHl61Qg5yV/iESYr2IRN4QrZyXmFh0R5DnI6vc1kI4RXOTixhNagxZuPvCyIrdYD0KOQd1E0JRYtF0QLgGOseHAnN4x2G3fnvjD7LlC8a9o2EM158SBiBzqRI0H6mTB9v45pNkLieXhuJjyXCNd4OCcqgtLaPS8CKseB5NR1BHfD5AgsO5NWlUGmD17SkR/N9WJ0V26D9TUYpFkRcC0sSl4rw4DtREAuFvJ2TunzkKVEnLCCh@F1Hi7qd1GUfEhlAvZxMn18SqKATNoYK/aRTNVSzbHsR3z6MQwhCcvwrAuPjuVN1Y43SjEhIsRJDsQE3sOOzbZWjbBk9EDiUJuRa9uPZU1MST1SpsngE94zDWtOG4lxidLMEOPG1JNAOhS8FENBOLGisaDl1oLIExF5EkOLUEtBslJwfDvZwCFr0028ilPoH/EnaOxJ4gK41PzAB5zyMc88XwhLMoiE7pI8n01JaYI3CHNPkalbepEo7ck0xvlC4qWLI9B2DyVFmKbJl@u67sjpLIVyIi4oAkkxw/cwRHA6AtCD6ruoCDHwRvpNfkX63OiDVmibY7aDOrVBhpOkxFoo3tLto2kvtGfJ/NFgYFvisB27otU2YVKouI4LQxHGmNKgSQe4a4fDZ9El1i4hksYOEfOVxW/DFgH@6Pyc3y7M8H4/EK14Ybk11KQdZ8IvPsazaUW@IinuS0cBbMOwL0YELzneesKbrDUpsMDDs9rl7Vtcw42rcnirMXRpZUn60chqX@x@zoqFwqZeWNVjLAumqgva6hrdnxyoSEFAsaAXCuv6miTtuoMJ32@itFXEtZZDhFn2HDv611A38apxx5R2oMcgQB9vRje9S7OjSdKx2aE54NaIOIJVmS4Pd4LD9@gDuhUaIcLrv/0sv@Mbahg@sX/mBgXatNs5K@ES78D0@taQLwS7lxbeSh4ua3dd23avaCIaV5Q5PzBS3xwCU1ZUliSJjAUIWkh3oTP8wA1D3IJstNxLMu4h2AB6qoU2kWh9VsKTrXTDfSwxfo1qjBJIr20bVh@r0xwC8OhLxIGAAMhaZ9Q2b6VBIiI@kYbgeueO2x6huQQjKJk8SD@X2go0d9OzQPpGDKZSoWgx2qGAT58dnLCTw/3TNzvHewzcR8eHrw@e7j1lT75mp8/22O7h0ddk8JU9O3wO0uWE7bx8Cr4vT48Pnrw6PQQPeecEYsoUIO28/JrtfXV0vHdywg6P2cGLo@cHgA3QH@@8PD3YO8myg5e7z19BZ/15lgEG9vLwlD0/eHFwCmCnh1lKNYgmRfHY4T57sXe8@wxed54cPD84/ZpS3D84fYmJ7UNqO@xo5/j0YPfV851jdvTq@OjwZI9hxqSnBye7z3cOXuw91SB9SJPtvd57ecpOnu08fz6V0cM3L/eOkfhELp/sAZU7T57vUUqUz6cHx3u7p5ihyLULzAMCn2fZydHe7gE69r7ag@zsHH@dFUhP9n70CoAgkD3debHzOWROUu7gCpTL7qvjvRdINHDi5NWTk9OD01ene@zzw8OnxOuTvePXB7t7JxUmPT88IYa9OtnLMrztg5IGHMAtCAf3k1cnB8S3g5en0Ge8Ojo9OHypQiG/AcYAlTsQ9Skx@PAlzy0w6fD4a8SKfKACyLI3z/bA/xh5StzaQS6cANd2T@NgkCAw8TSeTfZy7/PnB5/vvdzdw@BDRPPm4GRPhQI7OEEAwInpvtmBRF9RrrGcgC7uhMoqBTU3S8XJDvbZztPXB0i5gIYacHIgaguxbfeZ4LmGJmTnLrnduoA3u8onpkJut9yze/h0DzQ@bpVPjvxfQadTSi7eJcKgowkD4VWsglJf1eyYrdF503K6Lg7Nw2h8Bbvvn2fRvLzKFLzd5ZYbBsRCOUVIpZrN1ztNGOeeNJtq9j4xE2TcFUMcjb8NShV5tF2jQ8P8xNxSnFG1h8IAT5Zbw4jPtTwMJx9Uls93TBENN5Ig4mCaSFiKAmQdlIy0w8RwWCxJWmJOzhWRGbPpyaJgedP14cf5GL3wviHmAcKZ71vI53EMS2SgOToW0g@JkKU2Ya6N9gFYXUpS803z4lwpxJPDIb@YoFKDOAQ7hGHguaLeEb1lnk9Fz03HJ2JxBxApK4GNnsB2Dr@YGd8Ey5goF82jnCl8ao8eakANJQRKocqTou1FYveJ8pBHx0PffK5QrYT2XchG24udrw7e4GCuUFyrTPk/C/1528KtgGhwEPq7OsVr0ONZgwNAA7Nw@AUssSZ8STWfj8UBrYz0yRAYDQj1EOjK6kCfil11z6RuHc0WcRsO8fjQGXvWOE49iOHPj3dePHm1vw@SE6ldK61vblQkYQbJG36V5c@vMR2ybYvcBS36ygI1jYJirWQX9J79GQuGMZOLWHoIiObDg0IjT7yYOjzOzHUEbvSMTwNhdn00@@Sg5TMZLTd5Mr9dfkkK6uvclikqgJLIqoq56Rtj0vANUJWoDrT50WV7QqU2xh/EHTb/oImHGRIVSFQxsz8YTqDmwuCC5J68H@wCpbENbfFCEE0O6vHACPYgccagzKStsbhFkt5E3Y6VIui1WNDYXqnYKSYQsTRNRWA5j@xgQhJHrh@0YO5pgc9Xor6B82thsRGD0P7WzvAE2LgfxswFFhX5nLNoGAJzo1aFInr4MExpm@FEqiqI4vP/SXt@8dZApPANDWwKcbDzKORzGEKT0I/TKrvmNRVNrSCeiqix4h1q7rzsCCyVwE6NeA/M@jGOK7LyR15XYRpSAPJ1ABKyM8Gm34kfhP@/IE/m4N@GASdgj7hFcthyRuY9OUlYOa9g9EpMsa6CHWOxbWoRN@NeX0dobuIF0wszJrbhjfnCErBAlM4k8Pia23lV5jAAKznOa8TbL1pVoEbcM2Dk9Jja7gO@0u857f5ACaykBl3FDN5GlnSubLBFDl9UvoRfYLHknqPRu8d0@JZkBg64QIq1JuwzX@Y4MjrJHMx0foUmPcJWTlUT2aAHLTyqTgXRtILGPxY7jKJephOE3oAqutgCa7gcgoYeEwI/WAEJBAjtfYpnWLAN0qwhoXPzjdvvaZafiV4cr/cBEchthp/S7mnf6NKYGbsisdUZ91Rjkojns44wpNkyh1fYXdgcO23xjrAx5TPaZY6JiLnIUI0IhK@qAdepk70KqadpSqyvIfWvnAsHb84w@RRXAKElzHLGz8Vr7IVBFjrt@@VbjhLPIFtryfQPHNr23ubrlTg1RyN3SAVH@p/5EUdA47xC7RL6oYhLRvsCPeWgjlpXOWsMD0orJ3IeGJqEMQOZEZ6n9N8sHBBgXZnaA8vkMyecRCrzjqz6WaC@oIu33dD1NbrEPHMVMgXEgQ9umBVqEJKMehNu0pxtbURfeNahKKVo82kZNKerK61ljPqG0zX6lj2hXafv3Z6T952RP9AGEzS2npwNpHtBAA5oH5rsjeV03CufPYHmgBNJJy9fnRwlJ/5iM1@7fOaLsS8gDfaEUpZm0HfxIIvvdodQNGaFTcRtUV403UPzhGKmhaa1JuiBp4U8qkCQbj/UjD9/@Yp9bjqmB/rgEe25ZM@ttumA@ABlinZh@j0uaRB8H1M/EamzfdRdaGanwkyLJnXCuT1JJCCwZbFqKdAUgWBP2LrGufkJVPXYnKA2m@EoX51gUqnnDsRhDZw0RWWTT3F2R3ZWQoPabw5On@FgnA/MaW4GurVgrg/nErnq1OeTtZAZz3CGE2CKND15A2TfNXejMTqrARilxeykQV0f79/p4LSf7UNW8aovIQWoB4GmalqXaMGXpuHuU0a0z1ZMm0V8q4hDr1lxF40QHYnSk6LSy6Ihdy3L1rfYqYl1lx3ZRhtGWOxkhNFXV0EPfOL6QwR9scNYoajrek5fxSnaVyc7GjUE/AZmXSXp4MXR4fEpMFLYLQoqRthnIvPJkirfjQXsyKE9Vcj9OxTIATxIzOI7Yh6q4IFxBbnCVyzksgxl3zZwuhdy6CfVYZqSxSl51yNrrnhYB6pQojlCqv4VCl@@NEIpxbBnyZ6ssAjLu5aQTjpiSRHeIW021Csb10PfUWTyAwFgjskPYnk0MugIW0RQJn2zH1JvDYPe3eAA0rQh2pBhfC4VKkc6m0YtCbinxvF0TNwj4aNJp75/2fZAthiXUOVwC0twYgnqDMkmNcyN0bJsC9oA0NXuudjhcHEVFARNQcTN1EpU4qEBROyQiJY5JqSgdXXcfgjKqZKk8ISe8B/4k7bLUucwzMaRlj8wzQ6ZrxoNuH0mDNegldvQc/Cze@XIcJOUKtC@SQ@EDdrJA9k3svFAPx7AbPEyl4LcQK0Kznye9nBYzxFBjk6G1EjRjK4yZ4SdZbjOq1KxG1AhMK6KjFhw@hJQDLK4KAVUQXlThSAXVZcs3R5F5T19OBMjkoVIf5AMQFx8VddMBgToMe/COQPAK2k1JGDq3GdADD@zxN2JObDkC@YX953imTaF5xEyN1FDZu5baNeczw247NzFXwTWAo7xNUKT1ghnTpPiVZM64JuG1GchASq06haDLM7BmZuLc3U@zpzAKRYrD5xLOk@Hsaha8FxwEx0uyEdkRJT9z91A9NKpP9vlC0xh7s9tt4XGNEFSQGr4mGSjgo170wgsweh4KD/ZmTQCuh1kSZAuzjYFugvbhvZh1th2MGNRO3N4QYmAKm9LdHyMUd9FzYmc@CNaFDnlhEVR1DqmTIoiedwXZDeilQVK4SOXWdQycSdOHF6knIzST0TRp6II4pJRWokoRSk6Pj5VuhgDRT8@kzkL9BLalUQlwKphARWkvjHmo5sCHQakaRq04504uFhsiAqCgPU2C88XInhDiuxmJJbteRrBK23Box3f8rJMdkgLSSNU42DrHokBgkqET8g2i6OIDKmCDfQS2uRQA2JEvrYpihOTVGGGeYCUyLaHZ7WUeCpqmaUGBl81RCgfO7Z40nXiAa7Sy/C3whSRQC5OLAdCWwdCFALjyR5GHYayvFgCOViQop6Z3mICDkpQ4vKbtozxbkBREu0qkNwhTu6ckd2ACv05OkpJ4oeyfdDruC/2KDHRcIIKH9qWF0qeOYbhGa0xEwrqf8IZa@HJDU2E0kMQX49SbgS9RjIXC6Gnu5J5MLFeJeTCbcABs0M@LQRe3NsQ63AOAeUdB4@x7jlOEgvWBV1w2ucsIy3FGtJZdLdtcQmVZFtM6PK42TkCOFnkAXHZqVxJMfsyIofT3YiU6DkTlUSJveHdOewzbl2YI1KlRCzk/6ICx@2O8Ya9EE7ncKLYF9WIEFdQ7rdVixA4KPfbqgUHjhX77dUiMDAdspbiT9eLRElwFuCmRDFioDmluAwKAsZxqPEUFBE0acQNzJi2MofamFQVc53SjKoUskjYk0umQY8xLxhx/ViyOgLz6mFpNKLcQh/XvjA7oZkMkftwiFSTk10CL81p61CY6SAFKqOGiveYhBFAYvNJMDFm7vO9m2RmKM0HLDQGRVOq573k6d4E2qBXKaizCmVgUikifnsu8blZ01bREKs8e2lPuLtMUI0bnlyvg9CyNGfFV7qDqkyMqmTuYiWUZPECTLl7YcrdA1M@hkk07FXoL8mZ8tB4sHkXirOzWRz0eAsDKYEDJG3HwklsHAdfGZO7cC6BspWiPXUG31UWRoj05LtwPJrGQcbae@FqnPDsGTjr9sH03GlTaQs5m6wrcygKqUrNkpVFskhq03hXwAWqEo1ttYtWzwpHAqm7S5rblBCRcStxL1wESiVNHYXIovavL@BfNlasyfbACU9Mw4C2LH1ic9CQEXyGiR8VCyPEBFlyHCoCkoy4PXRa@NFoddrSBFqhXxhNvTMnj/mET2zSSYescYmVqHHBEC4STkFvFci3ecOzO9NPzU1/4A5Ax@nOJYDg@ziPzyelpkR6pJpODa3v1ZfN7c9m8xXX26YMxt2/kT@cyXoRso4H06FRO@aV6P1vwyzyEpTAb6HJ14M6soDIz@YSiQvthpjcYs6o3zI96T5NncfQ8MHHSItrriSlUmynDUNmYbiIro0im8qmSBLVYKwIPhsNcL3G55s7sXHjHJnJK/A0LF7pTtCajEnQHG3fNBxhyUh0mOcerl@EsFm0qY6HuygFy2kDo30zNv35jl8U0jFFCO5IvoWtlfllj7WarpznVGSjlARZXNdUJskxLfddoOCEWg1BlacVlaDu4GLoCtfMhb4Eirk6fwrsPtrTbQoRVOJFSYoB7xTq2@toeTEzR4OQlWHR3IOV89StcJb7HurW5L7q1n8BTk4XqBRzC@1BdLDlO4Xa9CCfbskNrGX355hueX26v58weNKaBKOCvumtFwoFNIIzcyUeLlDgKrHl5pPQeZwTzw@uvvBet/IYNXkJ3tw78JAGAEVoXJrAeoJLEyPob2JWuXA@x8FTOe99Dskt8HQYbeO0ws3tr0@p8hFKZJ5ZZu8wg5i/dyy4cxoURz5kEFiC/WYQG9XQSznYJgfsQY8uWtQJt6QRMho3i1MLuPBRrV1LD8S9kDTPh3f4qNfRMUT5mWnbbpa9cT27syTz06HJCPv78QgFDoJbCXnj8elOiSwzLy07dq8GgsTuO@cXM@Glu3z2k84yeeYAV9IU7MeOzfO98UCR629lqJiQ5QxmM8PkBh7vOZehi/p/23vT5TaaLTHwN/EUJVASAWIHF5GEwE8gCS4SRVJcRFEUL4SlQBYJoEoogAQk8ca0x/bMxExMhN3t9rjHdscs7Zmw/9oOLxHzCLffwX4Bv8Gds2RmZRUKJKVPd@v4dO9HVGVlnsw8mXnynMyzROkK/X6w7MYMmv2g3O2qE6sTnoKZYQ8UtlTeE7RoBiNvsnYwnqesQpdRmSPmyxJnvzCMs/tzI1LDm5u@tK1ODLqOnyNoLkem3zS81JMx2RVyox8GuSbiMMswRJvQb@LDStwW0OnU9//D0208OUDjRjrjVSaxmr8xvR/yMB5XlnHdazZhefFJ/LJ0NSbBEalM5UhLAVEjBrZrfuoDPxObarrC7R2q2hwMO3VfQ07zZ0lDOMcr/Lw@RuQKFMsP8IlqE69SsKzX@xRcxaNndAyHChSjdAcLVLBAJPKkXvx0EyuVSsZjJ5EwSqUVeEiljNJKyVjDhJUVYw3eV/D9aTE/N1dgzbm1@BdIXJGJt8YKwKAtCAO5rcErfKP4TChK4RA/zhQfJwuPK8XnywU3c1paOctkzuHpv/7ZP/yvf@/PMyXx8tf4skIvp79SmdLpdOZx/cvjp7cFfD9dO5t6XDt97JxNnRdwliG5P@q61VZVMxNL139IMF1pOV@PG8DRxovFKWPq61d@@tDzHrveI0Y@8IpXW85FlYobBGG5OFWaevoUnp4Xp95PxdFzh0ivqvTPkG7EkZbTfTGhlq6PSwerW1t6cCEVtLSJnCZeuFeFcprVcS3o1MdJeXueOjXSaeMsZXxUzUOF7gpn9DfRmEKNUW7Mr0UjZe9I@560VKliVj8lBSPWe2JttLZ7TupFUkGJvpEyGBZ60lhi1TmCkQCCh/kLbJQa4@WG3Yfmoq5bMXWam587S01OTlLNpJ1bqROZo9ocL75xXVOWJU039qjnwJKBviM0bPKpAQARGZOTT@rQjqd14cehQwElscPkr3BqckpzjWFAk0wORTih4vcaxG0IyzLcYal1sJn3ydwaeYPhQxX3oAEqbLrxxaCQvlGOVDvUIghq0YPR40kwtLxy0OkFl6fY8hJgPeCJIQiQkQfSPc2gouijfAd2Y3RSfRQhfoxZebMkLO7t1vC8hRE3yWjCvQHqBJiPi8FqdaRXRKyBS9bMJl588ormAfOM9ogxNNEWtlPH2wV0QtpCz7vM8MlYy8BBwnpADkf44WiizXes1WFTAbsJj7Dho0NEjilN0zBBzp14QuGlGrmI4fKSDkw7wLs6nBOxCu@emi1ND1TyFgoaE6MKl05clKQLPTHTnFPU6MudyQgAcbGSorRWlMoOcJVtFEHxUASQgjnT5LAWSMPQ@NjqfAyLNU1ailQlV5NnTWSgWKoaS1y8UnVs9BuNc2/QvW2n2hPodWzXtYSiihgm0sJhK@EuQP0wFeHKxGzRo3FPO2pF6f2TU8kcwDzHczD2OQK1QyfFLPBlROVN1DxkvbhJnz4uhWRHklsze1adTaW49keSFjvkDgRT2W/K2IpAeGB1UDnAVMMHQ1ihCk1QGmoPDuEJrZJx/V8o1rtKOJMqRtxe6bXFOVWTQ43OBw9JHkQ1EwiAHymijXQ4JTA44ZuYLfPc6vnKJNnoWtiXci9uJepxkX8kjUcNuwHMom6QDIetSMJHgW@phI2EV34DQrvA2tXhc092Bnc11sVSJblL5DhjYXR@KHokm6O3GlYwoA@Xb9I/QrS54l5nuTyPeUy8qWp4o3BnDQRcNJHpxTRZ8hMAQS2COEmdYlDgADaAnAaWgUeFsz7w2gTGya3v5ESjAujl4WKWYIR4y/kiW3obEuT@d1mvbyhrXXQ1C4sPcuE8gD3aUyavQY5O3eNuFMjQFXhjSkYdya9F9kvdfgs4f1ZSFzuKHkfeq1S1I1CV7LoY4RRxSo50WHY6pY9loKjsr1f6zF86NcW@G75IDw4xjdNx4sKxg/g6wZs57KYSLrtmiGXl6630ISFcMCjNdDk6AuW0vVabiB7UdUdq7g3ObdjUkDK8pPKyz4KzQNUYHTjBIt9DIp@u7x@CpFs6win1e/ZW78fz9HR2R62xmiqRYtUDX1AFNliwCNV4RjzB4ynFvf5BYgHSAQsIAVuqVF0TniMR5jyEhBl97Z6v2INYNvkh@iGazM0vxqMkJys@bLLugmQ0WTdRo7qLUoIpZE/YiYWG3LXJJLxbsxoN4DhExAUoKmpTnyoC7CmekH9R5M5N0VYbJSJuRjVa7qZgEClB4JqenW71vF2lxx37sFsdbsEmRK@7HR7PA4S3D5sRRl6lL/u8RksNYDWitygne3PiQV2kI/MqcD71HrEGPZNdJSh2IQQB5ggCuE7Vf9ffWQ0Nev/57EJxz7RvwqB@ZA7FZd3wj@wT8COJAGieAHJahdNgbgoRxiV/dvxIn1ggCDKQ@EFa8mipXIJZ/ZaxjGV8Lv08j2o08WJUG5dKGi2YoFkpct3dFZstHz@q1rsfhWDTq19U2v1WzxI9G@mW7BcWShqMij6GJRHdRC@C6A3PKqIB1HP6SO6VJY@OR4ZB3Gn9QLinFqxST5YhQuVhQQhhEoomP0p0U//p2NFjGoSowh7c87M0P7K3hTvGhrn7ZSlqoIN1dOKmDQf1F3GuiRvscVDts4bq9SOf8IHtAKRgM6YdpMlMmm/1McYRRhfwREzU4P4@ZPY/ZSGXUxBlFQ9LUi4VatRMwzxZn@yHk0Y2RbcFulQLM4UKu3ZbalsKcUITXrXY0LCC0IL8Dy2w3iO5@bg/DVXSPlPnXR75FpqPOZSGcRo6FRNDO7M@CtRXnRnROQkiOY7wgMZ4jmpOK3GvDyEbLJRATm5zkMmWHJPqaQh5AxAjm2dSsREjn@KSe1McEGWFOdWQRFXsbt7GJi6D8VTP28FkW/08pc6yG94G6vGsIUK4mgb3IsocRVTu@xDF7QrDE3/5YWjyI8CPpdtIJGz6KtIhDEb1ta58BYzQJULcI8UIB2CEMLp0r6k1LAgOBlBy9ouSGZ42SudAFv28MGsNVL00lnpYgHQDvqHUQRyb1PS75hJwxMBdReA/YHmRSpF9nO8EBFjWTERlIk8QiA3CtzqNEL7JjMxkPCJuZjOsShTLPcvFqZIH1BTxxc34ZvaeySBexTRH3FzghkIsx7RREa5C7t/9aK8bcyzt61/okTRQZO9QmsnztOOgye59p9SZSRlhywDwRtz4zgNqOivJ8x6E5zyZycgENIE5DVTYgsqodEIc8LomdMORJjN8nOs5/mD5UB50/zGdf0scu@SSX80AxSBkJXeA/BlCFQMsOARSJaQFOvXEnQJUK4P50Fo8Vo3YRUKtbybLHTwnturQAyE1KrRLu/JMkVht7VQx9NRUnhAZk6HFjBjb91ZbdHVk1vEgXJ1SuXHtPFgcO2SmpLdobBa7RFEgfeRK787Tp4ZoGx1ZB3iMUEHfhyhuhw8ZHzpMnINTF4gQJhLixZYCy0RxfU7o@QNnEDm81fk0nBFB8urxId4JTcbDe7@jMB@OHSp6F36wQ@d2wJUA4YTj10knj15rIt@K0CA@75mkdKD3pzNLv2kkHjpVlaP08LnIe/GzHO/F@t4zdDN42oC7D/vjZ48@5ELG23@Mad3N0gTvv3RMAX94gmLcrmpPuQsDau/2WHM07il5uL2026Ptq@BdP6Icx3tStdGA7biP1vjDHoBAQ3yKVKfhmQu5JFJ824YphXSuXpBCEDGxKUHJTJT25DKDBDNN/JX@xwhTTeGwaQLAkXoR@WzBqyu7zh7AUAkQDwdIr5Tk2hyLRSgQccFTfBWOVCaa7I@8KVYy98CYrohqRR9Ee6gTzGOtdKu9B7FY3pUcW7cbHfQGi7EGAvPQTUcw5ua3smQP4cumH8yXTU7Tmfa0x55NTzrAW8x8J4zfL5/mHdACnKhqeRQXKh3gk8gBKIYBag2T@mG@oFr6ldv3s32/sC9/rBvD9B89@zKt0F/3MzHTHhNTD2VivAyiVB0P3qicyk/kAZZthyTkacH2cH22vz5YN7I@O7Q@10QPw4aXTxS2qVpMDqm2d2OLEmqiigrp/DG0IqS1vKY/RsXa/mjERhc0j7e3Dc/8sg3/3d6GMwoXGFbgnp1GG/pfxv7vwtijo/rWQnYhW/lh974qLapPrGjgvtUwoo@M3PJPzz4M1rIfBouzu58me5PL@cxxF357k58m5xcm@REe4G1Gvl1PLk8@x2zzt5PDTLFYhEcBpbQOUJZfKpiYa/gc/izPSbjzw8nlVJGKf51cnoeHXD4PLfkwKC9@GCxk8b9o4Y@J/dBvVxTzMQ6qQ94rxYbgypBdSnC3XQ/kqrY7bOEUkOK4/4AUd34AmqIGo/LMIL@QFbwKTCD2sneNHgitZk/ZVAn@kfx89chbIVtcSC97QlePC8EKUFXE4YeqoN1esF6eZz/p1A@5BK/Rxscn6Xm8uv4onP2pBij3fsRmsio3iBcxqhgdGePvcvanqHL/txQV3gGjusa/uNsUu@LCjDoonogY0xMlY6o1M9NTRi0U1qzaOe9Xz80pXVMcMmP@1NrB7uqr8iFrF5Km8eruTho/HcD00cQBDC/LvqFoUkEuvF8/XN1DU/6jtT0qc0xWG5SKl2ZpUcvjrcaSge1K15PXRi49gw735jLZ2UxuzsgtLGWfLeXngWCaddcoDxzx9BiLGtStEW99cxMlzIPfhEu2JWNjb5tKkHXQ9MRa@fWusbuzfZKWqZzuj2mwuvu67MUoCPFft1U@QADkDL6J7jEYYYG9COMsuyFbFBoy9fzp1a5TzQA7GUiGBEyEL/70fscCKkdpQh46KKl9DMDD1tOVOyAtvYlpYLpQj@Qi6z4z5vrvPme7c4@M@uzO1DOjnt3pzDx/ZrSy4n9Ga7Y9s288evSIArBNohJoM/JQquu1aet9eSI2P2tMk5/muPdlZ3dvIivfJo73Dydy6tv@2kRevWytT8yolzK8zaq39eO1iTn1tlJ6NTHvFdtZnXim3tbKqxMLmlv9nYlFD@bO2kQuq9gFlAcnOCApB5GHTPGC7yvGk8OHQDIgIuZzaG1MT99c2KzaUBsGcjfM@3LL7P4g3WjSdop4BVI8bQNLPd0227wfREL2A2Na2w@wQxPYIcni0O7wSFjFTIy6/hR2MU@kNQx58SSAWfIf6wnE4g7NiAHH1Am7k0dBAbinnaPtba7MEUIA5WSJIBoC03bYPRr6QICu0xUJDg4PiwyErVgHUna79Y1mJDiagnGamMCYuH7sXldbSfL2ioazNwiXXL@SpFtAY6iW4GfYE0oshvIbXs3XqUGkvVneXeceAgTcOnw1xDkQL2KKPhNkvLyRbx96/teu/xVFU7pcZeDcLIbHLS1i3rhf3VfezIrAkDhjEgkKxtcqiJhoLXXXzeGthToct3IZKsqSZiK@PYe3Rb75x3IJqhF2RciCAATCCH0TtxGvaUKBdiIzjaIzhdpqSrfrQF@EvrZ5Q0I1UNZgQwOjqlahGs4JPHUrBAiy@NRs4FiTN/4KvCN5hJkMLDksk6QhP@bm8SOe4CUN5GQLkSBNrVgdmLlm16OJcirAYqTR31kT8dcplCylcwL1GOgeRRBGYvEUl2@Ob6LVmTPlAnpIuWDe4qSJISI4393l9teo2DSvF/JbQdHf7y@5tb4k5xGXJi1kni@IVnXDL7tLictephH4AphNB0Vb6@Ian4AJ3VExKbVsZX@@VErT8ri9vxPlYC8efXMvkCyP7UX5gd34eb2Abc2bItALIPExgEsuqRKyiAKRDwMBeyGBoN58HwjYQL25BGvcB@AB5WHL9cqnvr08bNJLwaUM6xavzYkqcBH/a93/2vC/4vKlOOXPQR6aNb4aNXzKzRt4cw5PC/DQYFrpL9j0v9IBf9EwZZmmosBcAzoFRCVuyibOCwLEGClI2rU6FXZlDdBK65WtnfKh/yvCS7sV0fCLnt1pUR1xfzbRIPzuxvAlrloUayISmN@M7XEdScJn5eBwv1x6jfIcOqdUKyDIA8CfoPWIN4@baPzd6YDgAxUljdhByZiOG0@xZUpPDV8eXAUfEjTG1tjoO3mqSui0q3f/SpqUekgjHE3MiMWNrx8@wJaafWbk2s7XmfZM59lMwxjOPENml@EoHkRQeUlgdnhpegHDYXpW@63eUmhll9msMdudMXrmBXDcg2x3FL7QP8Lzomn2q0E6ysK7rVswbrpVx7Nfw33Rz9rczUXyKQDMA0zFZQxpuJ2Tc74E8ec4PemrZLC4LeSY4pvach9H629LitvynCodbcNvR70WX1TdCxAwImTMbDs9DskiPu7SidoeJnWlJ2EtyGGMnQ4KB1AhfoE5GmCS2GU36PtXhAosilz@jwI9yu@bzzEw3xHqfjsYoPC3h1H8YlRjJKJa5vZMh1qlNQPwlkUFYr1CELB978Jlntbi@JLgiterHICC/536fHcwjL57kQxJBvI8mqqmacg3NW1CvnXtViusSN9pYahHM@QbxnoPSQbCMOZLFw0D3DBQHXs3rAB7yvI@nJ1qCDzVEXx2pjka8WEe1pV/xIO@iw8xVCu7C9va1aYgMJdiBmpjPbmGdv3sLDMICBhodp@Ax2cDdns9oMiaalrFvZlEYZmC4CUkAQi9UbSq7VqjagyWUAts8CSXX4gnNYAaRBheq11tjYNpaEDxcG8UyKRxQHNf2kG6CjROwSBcr3zAXSEVsJ078nv@rzAvDr7MPEHuyeUXNZlDlpwHbml04lD6KVrp@lwceZ7hxnciF9cR@nOrT31r9SmtflyT31V10Tj1t@Msob0vpaRvU@yjXODfVZFstb@2@Df1WJ81pnk1ZvrWbLulVSNiVfuqVWAEBVJzSnaFwGPCA4kEwtIBfQN9oeFjchda2tt/pikcuSzDFM9bDaRbqjWenJdXKng3UKmQK6tKBU@WKpWodO@PuyxsX/qmKxYbf0sDl1rhS65YNFWNJqOpFLmqSFmdaJIvcYpRF137VzCMdTTZAEGpGCWCVcE8F2bLKUZ3qakYR45KR8fXUdLqgA7eXwll4lq2yPsibMN9tvJ@QHV1vUv2A7pkByrrNMQ4PKS2faoN71buqgm/o6W@qGgVwzag0z7gidGxvunWu5Yj7yZuZOxk6UIdj/RFE7hel0768LZGNIl1JjFNjPWN3W1sWyRV02lf1HadRro36EXZBU4sLjwjxXU3XghgxA/mXoucoInIwzI2MwdV8vyriYalRU@1@S4ZNCiB3J7a0AZpVPOByYl7pGxvUp5NuniMGWiqR1hshxyRR/dgY4IB2LMd@Lsltwt4XjO9532go5gkSR08v4RljSWa4mGf1yo87dgpAgbTO3qmO2@32n08uIEn3pfNTlJwcl6zcMvHnnjxtMNcv2GOdOuyD/ylgBtPYPwU6NQpKqrjf4KhTrcbczHMH09fmIOGhZHMY/Fkbj7@JJeLn0VGiay4IvWxDmFAB6EQkz9gkDRGDEmzK1oDZZNRI8pMCJXNLaEBoDZ3JIlB9jmQZvOpJwKCniRVeW@/0lwqFX3iBV/cTXNjvAJ8yqRHmCLmPr6kWBBvxPRczLiFtBsDz4xtuA5BMmrxyB2S1J@MnKQPyR@pqPSHF4pGRJ/fsShzhwjzzdLKDxQLfmHof2Hov4Oh/2Hc/BiWPAhydMUH2PV72fBvZ7@CEYny38OH/SBG4Nk38QFa7KI7eIH792cV9Eff1r9zl478NnPYmD9et0ul0mE7193fKJ2XLkr7J/C@kt1OHF/OrqzdrGysNEpra@cvz1d3zDcLpdlt59W7hZON5udPJnDvm7sv339uOfWLyLt95@bY3LuZMRfcUr//aWtz2NtcOWqvHsydPLvJlltzzRXz01rLXXt9@O7V4cbcQeLm08u9l5/b2ba718xWF9szm6/n364OjzuRuWvrqLG@be22Dxrlo3x7e806WU@sZrcPFt/kstvlm/czqzeJuWxmy3m1u7F/dFkrv2/tb22fNFY/2dX5T1c3zlamsdhcvdx/G9mdeZPb/LS7e17OL25sZm7Wmk4jm99sdecu3@3vrRydbF68qpbb63NHi@8uh3vzF2/eXPd2Euezx/P91@5solN68yb/qrNxfV3ej9Sq9mF3xjy23@Scm5s9e7H9zHy1s3neftPNdTK7c28TB@3Dm7XySuvTs8HM0cnxm5vZg5P@6zcv3@9mrYODWrk679Qa@YPLw9lIvT2zlbg@Kh8tVDcax2/a11ubcydrmdcX5k6psde62jjffG8f7G1vlWbcfie3vXrdOtm4uHx9tba61bL3rlqd0mxmrnXYONndjRy9tGpr5uY792Xp8uIkM7dyNXuSaDgbh5efL65erhwc7S7kB3vDrL3q7tc2m4O1/fn8Qqbe@rT/uWm/zh29ScxfX77MWyelz73IzOfh3OJ268Rsd14m6ufvB59amcRRLrf6fuvzycnB5nW3VuocfXq7vn/Zfd3o7Lq72f2Xr17XWlcLvUvnfefgIFfPbphXrxPZamRwtOnCGJmH1blnh@3tN85gzf60v/Xenf@cuD6@mjHXrvbflj7tZ2s3Heddp7tttVezjd1q6a3dK/cHG/XF66Orzdb2p133JPK6nJubW7eb7krz7eziu8xGonm18W4ldzDI7nT2m7Pz3Z23b44tq3zx7ujzfn1u/a2z0O51zt98PmqXE@XtwcVncyFbax2cXHUiR3MH@3v5m84rq91b39x/Pd/bzW6/3WtsDnOlN2bupvNsdTi3NujOzxyvveueXG12nMyJ9am/lzWvE40Tpzf7xqo162@tevtV5ODlxdHO3tubrbn57ka7Y63sLWR3tjdXd84bs6@GW6/75e3aZWNj6535zjmcv8qXV47n194dzPQOr171FuvX7Zm9hcRhq907P0pEXvYv@s/2jruf3g7ez5baNXNmv3ViD5/l2qsvnfzgbam8@/n8as@xd3Lr@WHmaNu@amU/H9583nTnS8PEwuCo17Z7h7nBXO5NZObms9N76bx8c7C78nL3/cvqrGUdVy8P3jayM0cLGeuiO7M1P7@RK68325/ai2bu89rrmepM@yLhbl9lGquNo7fHV63L9qv2ZT2ysOjWV7be96t2uZbPZU9WmuU5c3tl@zBnHp2/Ophd28nuvWvsHX0aHDZW3/WP3u5a2fLly8Xt89l3@28XXz17f@geVo/td6@6O5HBwozt5uYX525mDhYXdi@6BzPHl4u9968u51dax7Xcy61821y3uu8WhgtXzueLm/ObAzNbO99Y@1Tdb5aBkh7tZatz/audwUFk5u1h@/qZs5I4uaq/etfJtRaOrWeZw0@Xi1cXF69u1uqzx6XPn6pzG5fm4sF6ptZan9tI7K@@2bs8Xzv@vDDbyK5sv62@G5QveieRN5vW2uXi8dXuYJh7s34wbJeyndbc9cHx3PWhvXJwvHmwcPG61m3WNi8vgDa0h0eXN/3rTfPZxeBm4dXF5dtqdvvdwmrHnd3LRl6aW@3G/uGrd6VEM28u9q53T3ac44XjwdzrBft40d5dsF6VmhuDN7vNcvaZYx0fDo7KF5mVVau9ADRlr3XUXd19s/n@@KWTjeQ78yufV@25Z58S14OT@ePMXmK7f1I/zLePu93Nd1Z3/d313rtXB6WtxFZtuLF3Vd09Kc8d7Kyuui8T69a8OdycuXFLqzOtph1x2yuDnUHXWZx5f7V9DjuB3VhsbBzOHHfcUql5s7VwUC6VNtza1svqYLDRfAZ7BP4rH7@1i5HffoZ/V80I/nxu8E81QpfekbZ7XrMHQC@vzG7LtuEB/kVqLdPs0V/4aViuE6ELyt9mpkci9YrovA6HqG3YyDyk0fpMuB3pu@hxRPpDR@VTh34jWohfFPha8JfOq9BJ2o3lUnC0lm2hyY6M4ds12aEaxQze7RjtIcqbPfRPKfyuoysJ2GYbMjquKYOXRibqdSPXqlQr7baVrhspW70ZH4GBcDrnqbrdaVrnRipVb7aq5y48tBr09DFyoHzBUZxnC72kUxW57Uo1l50TqqmWCPUYwUANezsbFLaK3FT6HDJeCIfoNZN8Q/XMjmtdm60hmfmZjXSENT5/vu75c3Sk2QvohgK7YXYDCqCOcFYmbloz0y/QoODFdEZcsSIzVKl2a1avW@0OK@zpuiK8dQidN8eve2ig6pS4oJW@29mnj/DDhFH@MKq6vxRirIfu9sPsKKS24fS0QyDZNIFfNMjTznjYVvv8R4H2wW5YftMPG3DVr3aH4dHOn7ik5KgySau/8rutw8p6aWv7aL98pwGgT@NSw3JBvjmaYyHRftHyUbVM1DCA5msK5lbnWoScYfsqzQre07ZMO@SxlaE57FJwVngSzZLqnkS4KvOUZ8JTrVVPPYRKxy5qDjywHCtocpbR/goLElO5yfe55vrdzb0xI1NrVTtX@FRgVVmQF7p1bbCEy1AFFo@yVF80/x0W9huKetY3qqHRrhoWyiAUYuUwH3VwOZO@vTCiiHDsAI6sVTRyWS@YgDDH8T5PS5Ub7ltc1iQCK/ir2u2TOSSHBuGK8HgmVihIj1LszUxqq2q9LnrYUE6htFagqaNMYgsS1c6kcXdruapHNB1IAyi8qawMhLlOVbPOhLHKWFoI@I7rnfEV9ZAjVYjQemTa6NkOIKEpZhw6lMY5wtqpI1hhTS81i0S8h9PsGQZC@Ul/WWLFXVxQ5C8OSUhceo0LNE41mn3IqTkMVXlTjwYKNbhxCC2ai4bFAWKlyzxvnDTgpxbiLWckCNuxkK@Pit66EKgXuKc80tccq@IawsyLcR0JoOg5u6mRrYZXNRv3BNtC5mC6t2qembyWBUIL8l0uQvVMXzykKKp6O6pLj7P7HARw@8axBmYrBgSzgoY4jgFJQmXJcfiBcij1pZpDOp45zQzw0aMYlDqlfJmFM@OpEcs9fx57lopR0pOFeFwtRlE8rxXXCgORXl42Yvnp2IwsPIuFAeSMH8BsOIA8A5idjuUkgLwAkJsDCMxiEJAnxgLPWj/gBQ2wgnvmz5ObD619Op/InT1/voA6nlpioHA@vOnTM4k8FGbQEwn/FwbLH7T0M3@PMG54XttHNBCziRkAwVUn/B@8WgMfVKV6nbNnoZvTD2NepJ2G3Hyo@AUQNrN7uoD9xZnKSumOAc8O2e5jotWB3cagvyqNp/Q0TnPgEQrCyeGFiUZTSeCTG70LsWnV0BmVf1fUjCMoB5IBQoKEYyWNy7v2utq3b3aYmY1Kuc9kV7oAYghQFKAYC1AYHeQjDqzzCvq1lPmyni9x3sCokh3yGs7ejZHtlzWxXT6hD2@4AV6d7ssrtIcwfmNQoLK9tYI/b8v7qDG7tbMBQziB/Uga3l9lU8sQVReFCSNFZoImfEavHTXBmyEKaaj89WOirF9Ak8BF/iB0Lki9wxzCe4jgDmleWL2KZQtojEo5j8we4ZFMEFWGBfT1P43esqstRMeQzToXhKXidEYAJlQ56BRQFBQNRAwhzg73SzsH67v7rwlze5XS9t5mCSGDgFmvdhvsPp6CT3XMFm@qCp8R3H4xoh/1qVpDKROlRqtdPWfzEJq9AnmQsUJfKpQabBH2lyf9SH5ODitAFEXlBqai0jCdENiou6qyic64IQB5FLnVYisUbQrbCWnDG90JJR1dRkpHuBTuQpsWogoEdaYnGQlvBaNvO2aXdzHko85pvnTZVcNMnvwkar5r2NO8Qn@VnLZJF1WMfQBptppUiaAsGqIwRGFo7z36wbYpau8VMIAxSvKmm1V8r8fm@plF4B4Zd9/F42oMEkPR3QoTD0RskaiZRszPOlp@lnFcZVzbJdd2CbUxwTUugwyZdXZ66WPEwtBjSfRcMm8sOTNmTwqeK0sYOQwG515goEE6C2GqQwOGw4T6Ql176KN1T@WQPZWr2FuJ4czd3UyZQKyfIxMbjrd/CoG50QC0xUbONshyRQSuZd8C5B7RvFH@D9jQSYoYlJ9mSgXYaZlPkk@0oRo7MxASUEOyljkV1Z3RpqLgxQRAjLrHGfTwZmSFKZ0qd4BaeMZpmiMKNn8nfwteIpJVsQt3G3KRU05vM@s2ggZdmAlT2eDQs0pgMz6uiCJjIHhEUsPnFRp4VvrAvGoqhab3fK5BPA2QW@wDNc/qhXdjYbQbonOSJ7PYAgZJnXjOMSnArF9B7oFUWXkhtN9aP6QxHBaOax3jAIG3nm3x0Z4xk5uZ0cx/d493jPl5zzp4u7x@aMzms57J8dbG5qExvxj5rnMy7zyB5yMuHDGgOK3YxUUO5lLdbLVgEfNPw8KtH9vGYvGAf4YFxVxNswTrCnIstgZXhRxBT9wmmlbmBrl0ZAKIIp0Bi/AYcvOGjOf9arfa6ZlsY0kulvhml10KQkHkYc2uyz5KUG0MKT5F/XX7GKcXD4AhpWHXSUkSYVA5GOl@m7SRksgwXJtddANg9YSh/wTRHDEdmDQs8ySQiZI4LMu5wSgUJIFWNB6yMBppW0bs8dGLeMoTu3K4naVWHm7naEujc98qsxWEXjFVCMf8HJkQCB7ZZkgen@axVvuuyuyR/rCjwdFNhoVTKYcLMLzHjEr@1lnIYQz7iNX3oIFQYiJQ1KezuLSBIwogTaDq8hyCM9HP4KwQkbBYGkUMoqcn6SqNaARxEbRL0ZaC/l/RDQVuK7a00Z2Q2g0xms9FWH1xoRkwFAZzyjxS5MApH@ccwjYymAPXJ@cY6DCgFbxQYYdQ@gcDhKHs3ZB80wyRUjg@x2VUHTzRIbmW2C5uP9ukhfdCrFGqtBCZCGkpfYprazk8G3dZZMPeadmgUUSPZKdktqM93W05Z6TW04HUXY331fbQxovqRjL5MPHApitE@NyQB4BCYRkwXdqYSTZTGx9mkmAQVdQkmLO07sVRhcCBpArcuppWgnlmWUZSEt03/SjJEbnUw3RemgNLgq6OOT273rCO8kyWXZXdpBFEYtVsWQ5tjf6@imWh91W40/d19pnWWWll7OtswAf/qH@HDjw0MXaYCu0QFZbL0SeNpPGkgZchIkXfo5Rv/hD657d11hbkr4reilT9U20lo1n1wmtV3B0iadfnO5ZDuFm5yHPxOG8BOcxudwpSuZ5LkZ96ZGeA6fGVy8fFsbOazhJEs1ngkLc4JQ@38xKSN2MIStH4NcOhLeiz2fVlltm@Ep3HBsRV3qYFPdXyarNIUGbfIvU89huxRELsZ0XfabBnQD12IupQBO3UTJTvLE80ZbQVQ/zG22Q4DFlEbPfe@i/oDRmObQiig@6IxF6n7ozYJcLtz70Z9Xg3R3BuwHc5efjzqeD5V4NPc1nJB8Qcj19Q0gHLAzpvIBhtyQziwRbF8HCUozRnfH7Pw8gnv4N29ACiFyNXEzpB4hbmNbHI0YSY0WbS6BBGORZloN00kHQQoqBzN5465OAtk0/hNSA/olPIQK984AwycqbTuAI7/yBWFr1qkpyqe//AgZ/GzuOVpSdnOWgcLLUd2A9n22mZbLmT266UdreUa6vx0dY5Y@RAuK1KmX1c5@ikir9UykewlaHDqV7aODC9SITIln0kcdLsxz9iIfSA1YHMGGjT7NQpYGnvBvUHBAA3rTfW9eLID2275rW@KixzuAFJFWX@HBDTr6WhAZl6teeaQzODBTO1FvxpVzFqVgZE8gz2MLPbMbeh9AHGvEpfVq@rkTWtYWQ5HagV@b2lSArPjuhLr@qYrD1CAeXJzWnNhrFR@qlCSKDwNxQxsYMuAM6rHF0MdpQBOoAVwRBJ41Zc6pDKg0lyxGx2cZ6IvSt2OCqH@3c6Dd/m4pFqv3eBATNgdbs2TpeuSbqpVNyn0xLQyeCF6VeiYDnfn1ZH51z362koFY9MRitrdx6i9xGm46G7qAzT/Mhk8HjUaVWHRvQGZhbqqKzOPsvOL6GsZZ13aBriaqE4uB7Hbg6crgk57E4U93FZtmVemy1jBofxreX2IeNBrw9diojQbDJjbGbJwGo0H10kX/ss@r1Ptt3ypzTRbsLwJGq0TDOM3Jgoe4BMkSz2BRMD58Gfn1Dl2bYdYwkeGmatf06bQUyLtYfWUdVkDQtU48uxWvwn@F2C37h04dhHt1Xo60z4r0J9ItsyTmGZn3l@DwsR6gUs/SK3vhD5VmfUfEoAuf2hw8RBgdmRWRr21i6e2lCFrFwsv2AXOXZI/IFeHYEkoL8pnJjkAiuTkScjU6WpeEG9rEzxVzo1ivGzd0QkHTJKdEj9hRCXkYTOELeLQgcEORwVrFKEKBMxxzyNFEB9VEphd4HVGjBzT04aOJxmuC9p3WAF7zM@7RIsSPBz7kzeYUG6Fnct4PRS8/7KoznxIM/bo84v1Rzh@HoESzrW5vlACf7ZIE4T6dA0qQ5UPS@lFBkReU4ONpY0BsY5nr6z@JQ0huK1Yd90CNKgmE0Oi7lCBEkf2iqYnX77CwojSS7Sd5KY@dYwgdoXIvhXSHRdrlytbtgliKwjIY8QocCkU5nOQfGSRu62wCH2gMZLEp@XwXb03obqYn3oILylUxBF6P9nvE0sPcE4k1QfXhnQQ04@5M@SXm2MRNXqwdC@ig2SQ4xsj/ZIy0LqwGdxOE@vQ@0T@SgR9zSCwOA5bKWK944VxF1MeeKtDIogIFWGRTzDY/9fyPDysiAHMph/yYCMqRRmRGfhktml74RmIH2DRAK/g1Dn/953llDKluVHvuPoEXwur8O/9ZzkER4qg2RlGJd6KVCiMpwmFCj1lNuR7lLzfkZ/R9ob6O8IPlR/x@BD9XcUn9/VX3Vi/I46AlsM/aCMgyL7TyBRQ26VyOcUPxmYmPV2qLWTYOm@A70IlsbGG6OlbYecyJpjWsB1hjSCvmvpUOdPXMcSPMcpLBORpIUsLL1z4PjdCC/xro38YoyeK/CH9y/gJ1t8ti32aEpAyIt0oq9eU4F3qEA49PUlSZKo@odVMU1ldgI985N@cdHQqiqohlNHWQYzqLDqfdzgVw2G1vWCCMomiyCi4kZYkT7yHVguWATTwosIrAv66C@FWDdCS8lBxNIyFLLAMpGd6JaIyKy47qh211Qh6gzTVeMnlByrznsHCTnBeTDopHcqIXdpEMW2mnTatsqK2MaeOJ1CsycKote1@@cXBjqKQh4Q83YCIUuAqzehoX30VbMk1eJiXvfV@XHGOHIMEPLJfh5X7us9Y9Ukz@h4liyCEWrbhNCwmpiQvJMeuJoovcp8xgd9fOLgVU9jpjVgDecDNIEcMEP1@zSdQiqWm5geAhCDcbadHnLWFncBu@8Vc/AaxiuIHID08UXMyoTKGt5YnsZaa6l1enO3YaqEtTYb2kgyQw02smbiUV/2jsbxKWLw7Aaag7Vja9bM38H4qVr59hrk/numJlQqZ2WSQ2dRsGecjg00zWtbKLFQOFacqSCBA8gdu4uy4TAZCvkGz@NodVVvQPYiURnzJdKiORcgz16jolFoabpxI2/iZDqAgKAFxFrx3Rnel00DMcDSr0kcVYVZAHaJlUO/s9wMu463zLLwKCYw7rXZwPjW3SrOFWpnDM0bxHKVt4QNq3ougg1I0iubQ@fRJC1eWHW2yljdw6Z0OQQ3CdvYmjSMJen9wFRYvTDrV5QX43x40FNWJwVo6/RSdtNwP/WrXZMibRuJKTciaDzvNPtCEyfIRwkCVfBlpplXHGVCtMzIfqIryMC0kud1eFQjaR4p62yaXXPKFRF8xZkR4lY/@8FTk7QB9EodyMD23BIWupZLcDTxO2lgXEMYDNtJ4zekhP7O6m/IWNYeFdmJoa@b2osvExNW/1cNolBD6SoIMdrGxU7MlOb@7IsjubGqMZlTnFvJWBp@FdIAlT68@a53yCjIO7@Az3R@HuN4GCJPE3UtuqYQIbBMNp6kSkbB0lY8CrVjd1I6ZM42ChjyYbb4Q8ev@HsaPwMZoA7SHiAwaP6OJ4z1Kh5WUtOF9AkrnXqJE1l0BegARt6tdky777aGv@uJEJkYoF284J0haUivJ@LVz46jGMbSWQaDARhbmV1Sd0PdBBTUgXjnt5fwS/RQkBocuLYt9lmjJcxgXJD3gPyYDbomih3it23xDTdHqRMQ@IIuE/CkB9UEemTjlWS1ASCdZC7W6aWpnFSwq9Z7fSKiFzYqV6BOad@kiN1tICOQTkOCBBv7gsBtx@xyZTDbhnbfkPszzFfP1ScQSM/XpgWViq2P4CNtxm7hvOeNBOAgbA0Uqhyem1oZIL/QcMiuRWul7Q2mCJ9R4ObGt1tA//HKKkvVwi/CttgGzqvwu2vjWzg888UqEXagXBbdCsBi007JROCSR0K@j0tBP6D/JOMiU4LMyxNK6PbjTQJpVYwey0kB1iqQokXMKqKmxnO0sIB1CVlPrbNHRbxrYa0NOjvDUbyBCWJWu/UL6BKMl4UTptclPDWshqHilWD0PHGZ4RoAvoi1MgPd6bdr6JKmSfhSZpp074GH5JAl5oGOU82e6aVFFM5KwHz@gKqedH7ciKu1xVWRXILCD2RU50i4g4o2VTgeEiEG3z3NJoWdZky84lFIHtGC76ciMSVCrQGGRj7lz6TneiXy5QtBiLk7IMYNLaiJzyQsQqGFPRWnG7t7xTdHeOzmyuiEyPWqsEtuRAshFRqSSR7OeWFNaD3jxnJR7d1/yCtnUw@IYosNethwykOwCrInlZaVNnKW5xaQsDqfQGXEJ9SM4rJ8c8mEXU0eeefKZ4hsG5TVTbcErov6UuCxFkeZbNfWbTUFd@WbGyKnmBEUPFW0HI/fxZGkrCNFYCgXN55lHGp8oiizFYS5U0pPuUXxn9sp0SfmitlZzsrVyPOjWOTZ4dWhlITrmqrutDRvYH0yH/qxy8OiCuDwfXgjisHHqQVjIPS7yNJqwBpeEwH52@AenyJLOjEx/BbsEC6UmrgWxolms1gGJHcoZcA8z42AlCcJ4y@h0P4EQ6Hhhbfmzoakqo2ueQ4/@xa2qOFOIb@kbr7TkTU@TNzb3do5LO9X9stvy/sHZSpJivzKoLjvZOikzL1B594dAXfK9TnEiRx3LdjHccehOEsogR/U7V7PWAdx1wRx/KoKJat9MzL2zj2/Pf7bkWt2l7j8oQiGjcb3pGnsWmgi1EdVJejfDQvgfD0cc@M8@WEPJIdUqPXaQk8GHBcqgjQTiDl/QfqJK6lm4zUvSxjCsgG3FLvZu0EOUEgT/jtm2GlaDVjNZlro2MrceOTg@UtQDhGQAYDvqHU7TEdOgIfS1ypGMbUw3FiV2or0nGTv1ayxx9WuUbXGGvcLechqy@6cR4T3BK0FxLnBpgVzzjSXJIrJKAiqQL0F9BSImOYecYcyKB9kculs5se5NPAusf9A3gq@wyT/O@28R@30Q@MnhZntyxgAvsBtfhs6X9ikUAu68GhNfoO6QEV5UdH3mZOPtyYX4Gf@wBbkYwzIRetmfz9G4z/WnvvBZtY/28fC798MJ3QC@6xy5PQNVTG9/XEGO38qViPfZi5ynxXFL6YT4aYTIqDatxhPULxxwCJyHlu7fGCPR03q@MeV2t0inFGAJ5NUy6doqyLY@JXmvXg0QhP5YUr0Pg16n1r570wdfnxfQ2wBvO6Gqx1/Q6814whfR7PfpAmvAvXco@Kua@vf@tov69XV9lGlvTtE3tM7SMM1J5rrV5EmavP1q@FTA2dLF9bxpekvNMyVeYt0Kq8dxklldLF3yDMzLhlQf@dDwZDSKshbT8TI4vBa/hBzYrbqNokiX7bgU4gXclRcwrodxV9Abd3DoHdYSk7E9EN80dbYNOIGA1HR3oC2B/HgGPlAeoex40D6h0aOxbjKxEIbsQlRN/B/V6yt1BRkA49fjKz@gEZWv1iN/GI18ovVyF1WI5OPMn23m6lZnQywZi0jdQPcf2QSFtTarnG8WTo0DjfLxvrR6ivjZPfIOC7tQMqusXe0sr21asB/5Z2DskEF1L@3ZhdV7g0Y@jWzbtLpfD6bnTUI8kiA8lnjoNo2Nu26eQ2T57lbbb@44Jd0x@wtc6nytdkd2nwd5KAyS09YTdBZEd81yRMntLiuwUxu4z2i9OWJbSRvni6fLJHtBYVDVwbcfLdHPAjpcdG1kjLagPw2pAKYKl/Jku40Xq0T09JIGwJx6t83YxCYwtcHRmlnDSN9rm0dbu3uHBjru/vwuneCbnaMtS10G7NyhJ8o4@vdta31rdUSJXADsmkDz9bIYP2uJqQxO2GlftXsY3iwFkqF4s3n1XsyEunY0irCNab6Hc99TwOmFN67s7PTArlojz0u7W@8Ra7G/GREoxjkUnOoLiwQHmfRaARqE1G0C@xMHVnLVI4JUntoPMbPhQidAdFz0pDA43RPbJlGdBWPEfFCmuJmM8MmQUNFjwA2gpKOYIsGRWCYmko@J5DLUBudHsja8GC1KV@w6AvhmBXlyEnppdUloBiccatT5zC6MgHmPWt1U7W9LmfAAyGRwBnwDAYTetUrcwsPSYw5kaPfQ8EfEuY54bLtrN8g14gGriJhhQOBLIg28bjRkGKAo6rV4XH0mTUxdaAYKVTEpfzoJKfVkkeupBIH/L@4Y8NbWcgZBSrYhJUthQrv2g1mA9D2i2qz5xqxYhxPg0EEMTsWa2qdt6og7tG5cBcNlq5RjYCqXSjiv2XpqF4ynBSIU4owtaHhb4cqtyY2fvOh5aDkykiNqLdHnUaFKRH/6d4GrIw04HvAAKCUTi/QrZDTI8aWwNhNMZVjrg0zEkQ@49f@qEZ2o183fQWErBO7tD5/jgskJ70imooPtU5p2GGoB7wIuUEfVOTmAoQY0pS8wNsoHsOYvwfe3XAblSG62MCPErmiNl14kDUKTRxRKfLzY2qtVckY7t5aacazbrAiX47yGUXX3y6b5dE1SQ3FZCXNuejPGZUY0LNTF928NA1ULBr2qCUc3CHi0Y5fG27m9FcLxeW1lQ@pX39MnmUy50wWqg2@vGClRL5mIZEclofSnSRtQLnSBNCI269haanPyNQSV7kEBozLhQXM94tKQX3jY9XR9A7Fy/KnU@LXr0UulSJ7E5pCGEnGo25J41RWmaQyZ0ZcAPBoJzQWPevKlCTBVPT6Bca1x1EoAEY6SEdIvUYPq0b6NZq3a7zQA8oSEXwaD7eCH5exyMWMon8xfTwyv4qtFBPL8YzMRYtJoTMmSXRSQs7FRa9ucXhpvxoBt3Y3OKDfDwe3cGfreHv4Jmhrd0L7pralEuNh8bakwXo42F/fAZY3t@8CC31PjgfMm@QoNDXT1eRMPp6Uc/6eGj@OjB2tPQCDey9GVFVAtdr6nRZ6iIvxoTg0jQrEdTAeQ3RwuFbe3zeiZTxlW4KyQPeqnTrZlyIZRNiPpKcjtkMmYpdWTJMKE6SYJ5lyy@al/mrvWsyhyBtDKgQPkhT4UMRCRe0FyWQgrCN4ZyEWAg2vmSBKzPlb90XSIPdUAL49RU0owxs0rYOR0G5O8ubDTvaJyHh4SzJv7F5ZjmJmzIFw1kVH1d2hDkgywrgdVM/x5jt8/I6ZP16S9TCDZX7qU4dRCb@O/vKNA6jYwZvitH8E7xgWOaSks0KzdFLijszy/Bz2z59QKhb7reCFNbIumGPRNOaPH2uR7Ig/fYH3/EPxsd4W552SxFPKc31A496mF/NvQcBkghhsvNBnBRQ/uxVbGGFD7ZNFxZDra@0xteZUtpKimQnYhfGZngAHPzcfJA/BqoDa3llV6sdUxbuEryYt7tZoDfIjQJ6fm5u5D3awF7J46ufC5j0kSD97bee6qoF0hy6pCsHM3dpJyu/eBLgDdUWQAhsxuWACBYHVCdlTfH2nzUhvH7Tlpou2eNCY3aPDJJ4XBWuNG4NA28Kh846kQ6csI33QlrDqKK@aEezf3l3dCgV1u6e@R99eHy82zITn4be/5TCZ@7aDpBIY8W6FvaKCSL7kolZcD0tw8EHl6VeLgflCxrE85XhzL/iGG22kucYXPfsK9fpl5EwR2yyK11DpdtX58hUPuL7SkSl/Q5sAUdZKGi8uWUeFI2u@aNikRNBUoSxfcCv9aUDmryt68M0lVB@kb5xBu8AsKgROPZ0yQO5ZwlMFGWpyKsFpwJ@opBQnwVztoeyh0qc5He0SLKc1VOkZTm@YGHhOpT4XUG6qKuLl1LLIGYyQORUVmems1moOK4R29fkn/gxsjEp6IhoDsmXLVqmPOBV1qmTSqSjb95LOOAkkKZU0KXLhxmT19LnkmuZVhQZZRJsDgFNJo2O1ztJCf@qnmJAd48KEo8cDCeXNTiNCg0IxTxUouSW8QNeyYgqdvrDO0qRAKQgQymTewPJCemF5BfTMkK6FvuRJxcWoAfhXNEI0VZ@8WPPpi0uc4V3TrfdNozxAGV/GRpSzkhyDTBrlnTVjd93Y390r@0FjiyvIo1ApqbBHoZhFw6g7cskmYcDtfu@iwonyNfj1xuSvEgS/q0wdu6tl4tfgV1kBgTjDZWl8@dr4apzC5u2oQYk14mdi0GWPVR/Sdbvf6X35OvhKwzsATi8NU@An4zaNhwQ/jaBFrETBYcvpQHdxGBYS@cqKdKvg1UIpVMtA@OawhcV1YM3HbwW0iKKfMHSwMolIewE5gUwiJbCR5VkS8S0BHfULL@Am3WUXjVgs2DDclNLpkeSE8UwFbjT1iLv@yh5YSWJcJYteJTzDFJy0i3FEvdriRsM2vlpfZWXepoJb/0JQ2lHYRt/NYhi1LYaWnS9P9kz7zLcSWp8bEf/TyIITI2j4442K2w1eEBjk3aPmRZ7jvmw0v0eyKeIgs/ECGslHq8CXkZfJSEYqPwqxEt5Kb@mFFAlvsbceR5szphYPXEiR8Fq8RvuHwlvrgdGo28CdcUASfKiAIKjtr6EjB9NmpOJxi9UIFhRTkcSZCtcZ4594SB2STHMOmI9n8jF3xqY3xpRe7M78fozoLRCd1xCCNIjcqeC2pqfngun6lmQsa8WDObRGBTIDzMBOdf9YsCcRX9INWmrxsiKjLRENHHktsTUCyTnTstIUGpM15c/Kq8bLC1kxC3FxuLNoWXkl@rMmwrNqk5/y61ADbdVWo8qaCM@qrY8RqKkwqP6siWDWEbpGhNKPe8XQTsfuHrz4GD5WB6dVZQ7Mer/HO410WgFrqAfLQ2e0RO6GdW71fjI8Roue0tAenLSzC8IjtkwDAX/umWJ9qIBktfUmiGo9gEgtNF7KCqmYj6N09s1jzBXz6MvPIa7xflzLeko59GEw2AOTaIhkMoRAI3cxyYrpqOFSg55RIGMkI2pMfoHXW@R@Tye/sLjDkd@jyWj8NsrNKvioKPRJJgv56PlziYt0z65YRui/gmg8wbAdww8j7SXd8c8Ho99TqXjEkWzZdT7sTCKsghTWTiEdBXC62AnAwNuU0b7IggDm7P524IXKKAxsQsK4q1M6DClUjcKYfjAMKbCNwkg9vB0kT4X15cmDYbAgGAYj82AYOANHcRqd/AIAbvlvNGyq@fCBZlEitZqs@aeGgln1vdWCfZGiqoH2ggTBl38QeAtrh2DM9bne0sSgB@EDhY5RfMQsXknLsBUT5c7yAXMOS8ZH1gsLt5TKJ7DayisYj91eAzaCdLOl1nfI4g@I6IFDEgGQzj1QiEnXL7ogIuFopoX0IRkQggntr1RQNatSoZOhvf3djf3S68pO6TUKUZNMo/D4BrVlSF0nm85jPHs@bamQTlHRQFUL7EaE6LD2jdonwJRpF6HIsVhq8ouW7zbKDBTWVKTzonTHvDHW4RMFrR@BiTnT6mwGhidGbVBEPZq6jsa9nPoOJnsl5LVlaAnl4XkiWkJ5tOSIJmxx@Q8d1lD50PnQ44w145RtMt0zvb0f0HBJK2gYqesPvbdmt4a6JCnltJRHEVXwUXYj51SociFO0D0I2gD@NpMxVqRTXGG/Vm3V0eVtv0mOb9tWq9quNapp58KJNN2icE8Tm2q66OQygspUW4fl/YPKHsbpKq@S5QT@K9C3w63X5d2jQ/xyAJ9mRHJ5f393v0IK6vtHe4foMTSQFNUzCiheNpHgy7Szu1na1vLwe1Q0kg1CXJA34Ue48kkallMZ0N8hmXkkWRWiQkF4yEwFi1Ja0uhZbdPuy@Bt6H9CbvBJtDzBSxmoS0Y1Joc0MTz@FN88X6e3Wi5qR7fv9CgracDHApiI@0twnrZ7jgXIF5ELfDtp06f5RBm/oSGf7cQCZdFABotFhH1X06XVgcvkYNipxyQ44cgz@cXsQE68bZrq95qphanbOHqVdEhpKFh4KgM7R4aco06FlxQYFFrpES2IkX7sWohIg3fIRRYlNAieZQoV4BvEgpFIWPEvET1AlPgEVJXjR30xNBt6fx4Rv2ZCGyN2a8p6vlA/ThD1JCxw1Bzh1z39UoommLifImOOU7Q8VzijX9lZPmGOqdGJ0f2UZ9edRu2RVWhwqRdjRy/ks8@bd@K6SzSggh@CI@7/BuDF3ZjoMFXIc9ztFQBRve7QYAtCt6fQBT0/w78D4dq1jgo0MZhwcT1vNMpf2R0lGgm5Pc5AYl50ObrkubFhswSlOMw5nus5cmE5fqXnyIfluNZzzITl@M1fcBarGUsk5OAtG/m5OdZm9o1nSPF/q4qnUjLvc6kK7RUGeHpxuRszkDLDELkTRTQH1fdsAK63bP7OlvlB/@bfAWwdliiVokq44Xc0@w7If/v3okt8QvcALP1v3EONQCFzIq682IQZzwtXxRSXTRK2pEFo/@EOaNGoHMXwsv/MmxG/GjNpfvMffXnCp81fynE3FP7kDdeEVzbnWTUEAfz7UQDFbwFQ4fJyfZG3UTbgxc/5JQVF9sADwFlm9Cz5YJawKr/eWWVWh5cLrTKnZ8k@pMrf/GdRp9i/QnL8S5WDaK1AZmjW/8@30Eg1HwqFZXU5J9rU7Hm3vmOzn/vboBcLy77nQaciZ3e3@2//LNhur2Ro/v8@dHJSAX1@yWEPRfz/9VAYM2NhfGQQqdRYvE1xjkRibI7f/I3XDkZvcJndtUj@9h/cXzo7vvR/55X2tvlluXEz1yCBBUmgUg/yf6Sipwoajx8gQKWEtEbbRtWa05Yc7sXCYMzfgZz6LCzO/J/z8vMw9POM@hwAfssMluSS0L8eMUbPOcIgsUbeM1n5MsMlPy4Xda4tzh3SuV1m1oWBOeBG8TjCFEdjepYDAse0T8gYBS2@xgWzdxshLrgQKvy41W71olPFAK2u3UmLCCCWnSm37UsLN6puBt1cpC/dcdLQz2GtCQDJcUUUX0uoUAFNFU5FWPeb5XbMWK3X@@1@C@/QikKuQsdImQy6jCNBsNNvuwIm7rgrfasFPSgip@axiCDmOdBK2oWBlX5Q9YGqw6odrTKTYb3xNLmhoyRqW71rOT2qrDgqC6DLJ2JQoQrruZZXsvBooP6FALEr2qLoz7bVMWNafoziaiW1BPKLkChyqQLNjCBONBhJ1ADZ6bd9EL6IESfdmCJ/Sbto8RPLJvOIORPnjdE1MUKIso6wXCMvfNCRaxkEIiyIun4o@eRsnLFEgPZgerb9OWaT@SxW5OAnclFEnqGVZnm1SW6LyKiVYBA0lZtGAThCD7zA63IWegcfVLuK0f/213/xf0TjXzIZmUYxdaxOFWQGikjiQcXXQ3tPvmvgUT4RtooB2P@nB5tBN8y61a5ihJqeBhom1xjIMIAI@QtMNHRaZbeA3tjnMc0XjKwQJ1YmU1pbMw4393eP0RqKDxFoFgSK4yRYMqIJRjuV9H0XisGYRcyE0TyvRcWYSTZiNJfqFWZTPSb3Os2YpoEF2PpH/wNhi87ybdR053UZAIifo@zUB88JUbdWB6sGQs5gHId/9A8Zsu2w9mw4YNuJiokJj44Jk18eRcZG@sU5wuv7L//8f6bqhEUJ8Hx4rtLWqx7H9NPXU3EgS3M2lTsb2ytfNYSEsYDvRdGf/ysC5nKQbkkIIxM6VVRAwrv9L/@JQTDw8gFGTytp@OAk7gX0lwxI3R4Q5sbCS90L758yvIZFtwA6oNrQ38XXsE@mu2g0FNOSM/eg77/8c9FiyG/18M7kjjqmfc2NhA7Gv9FHlsqK4Rg3vhr8sSP8L3Sgwsx1HETeqELh/MV/9pap3k12nczze0JbnYGmhXb4L/5T2OwjHXNYPegBnMHqQxW6Vsa0@X/9xwr@IDIxuGfC/Le//qu/8fo4GNuzwdj@/JW3mgajvRiMa/tEgCS9wy0jmhiMHYr/6K/Gt3IHRe11HID/MA7vAz@yB@OWPEx9tegH9yz7cUD@UgJRC35w75IfB@ufSlihiz3YrTHLfTB2mUvoYxZ6AP70mGbCYvzX@mIc3DXyY9f8@GnxvxNwZPjQeHRkWDIZweFkibV9buToFz3z4u9ysDU69cOjNo9xKQJHBeBQavLNPcw1eK6v/C/BmPK3zNd4qTnhbEH2SKslJ2oB0aTackOqKhZ/WF15RB2IeyG1LH9fJZHbTKZjstF932mg1EH3d22SPLp0/YfBA8Ip45/RWAK3DeIKW9uQe4JTavIZ3eC4I9MHwZHPISlqoAfoBogb9PtcdTeV4xSSNyaCUFo2s0QTdJyOotBYQURIEoncWahQwXJq6EL4fxQFYumqxtIVIkv0kfzIel/uJd5//jeKIiks2X7oAZCJ@2H@32IYSMWI7srJY4fg6caDLvrelCDlT5VbwNit@//VqUWguvG8pJZtHOR/9j@qjc50UZe1Af1Bk1fy@I/BMRExY3dAjX7yIwGIxac9kjG25v9JDrzLFGpc5biTPaCeMdX8q78fxakdjiT@XLhfyBIQx8pYxtaOcXRQ3jd2jw73jg7xQEZ3jKhk8PGCHovdTJdJgPUfEozIsgUQ8/MszmrfeHpZSSuRj1P3/5e/wu4z2EQxmo1qaLqz3L/wlcvJcnfgiIbiwRgS@Bkpz4cW0DquW/S2WFwQGAIBeqvTw/XqmvAgsvHBBDt8FnsbT382mdalblExw3nA0P/IbmmHMeMPE3CrwwEo5gwcv2L2l5nx@5kZdGQ1xNu7YthtHsOHXkiXn5T19z2DfCeb4Qe@Nzc36SaGp@p3rbTponsiFx3DZZxzYBY6Nh1qottsmHhWHWRbdF7Yr195T6l6tXNddVFB5qcBqkQXF58O@Tcy7ozYOW9zKI7vPSc2DDrtTQ6T9SQAS9bqV8nmTaMgPrBhsFI44UTkfrrype3KJ8tpqhx2D8/Z1ada66put4jbjdZasJFFvaq5hzLnUL6Kd8diwxh5iDwU3k8NYppjrEhh4KUBfYFH4KqkdbE1OB2e@YoPVHGfNovLETHvBMoKwfid9TgobMCAvw@8SmW1pwPhLF6ZkOHtAyqFyJwIZijz@CzC8cuAleKX8YYK0zDn0JeGlj/1IpWW@OY3GMeinBgwJxxAuBnLnP7qw@mHs45r3kyfJTLnSXR0hLlrwqyRcEo@e/gZsd@6bjm260vqmG6PFVyyMql@IWYDzxVWfBG4CmjcQLOUwo3lIQ21A4v0EUl0qRezhJkqaeNc0PV29DTq4Zgbdioag5i2pJKBSMOLJ83UXgd0pgHCdNUlGYkvTBcqetxFf1oybwpwjg5gOkM0I8RADf6lImKYGrf@VuFtGScA2tkHbqAr8jsMxWngk9bNWzH@evMffXPzm7AuwltPE5aJYkBpbGACwTXFcmGPmMtFbVyhBZnpagtd/kXLHXJPIxUH44XpjDRN4XqwCyLorDb4deF4gm9SO0ILBesaouxrDIu8LHldSJQqTRPvFp6@y4kgyjMB4QgiIcVMUWygFwNJlwkHXYuFFbvRGjmgRg64COcejGnkmSiGgTx1tw1n6LStCvsRwMuxRi@JhYZbvcb4VOyKaDqj6vRoDs0CaWEIA4rzrH4WWvup1miNaAUA4EQcAdAwm9V@q7cUCRK8XEq9KRrFqJQ0it/ENGBaAROMSHCBlcpiapKJGws8SrfI7SU8nUaiuWQ2maP/Zfm/aFImyv9yo4lZf86cPzGbDPzvd5J4hpgNF4ty2VkkyJH/Hw)

Languages that are not in the driver:
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4),
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60/156 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/download.html),
153 [l33t](http://web.archive.org/web/20051102205243/http://linuxfire.dhis.org:80/%7Ealecs/code/l33t.c),
154 [cockfuck](https://github.com/braincock/cockfuck) (perl version),
157 [Haskell(Hugs)](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/downloading.htm),
159 [Agda (too slow for driver)](https://tio.run/##VczNCoJAHATw@z7FINEhWP/QA0hi9gGFUN0iYt3VlFZX3O1S9Oyb3uwyML@ByYWtvJcK5JqONU9V9@AdjrE27dtQYlTBdAteWveHINM5Eg8laMq0YFI4RJBDCfW4MzYmuASvQS/bk61EX1A8KLdO6TpHMPtc9tk92Rzi7fm6un2DyQGi@ZKFNIL3SbZOsUtP6Q8),
161 [2L](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/2l/impl/2l_graue.c),
163 [1L_AOI](https://github.com/stasoid/1L_AOI) (`-eu` flag),
177 [1l_a](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/1l/impl/1l_a_mmi.c),
181 [Ropy](https://github.com/tormaroe/ropy/blob/master/ruby/ropy.rb)

### Explanation

This answer is based off of [BMO's answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153892/56656).  I use the same tactic.  I define `(!)` at the top level and then use an ambiguous bang pattern in a let clause so that we can split it.

Unfortunately I had to add parentheses in order to do this, because `!` can't be defined otherwise when bang patterns is on.  I would have liked not to but I had to.

The rest was pretty simple, I had to add a `_` to placate Dobela.  I added a `p` to satisfy alphuck.  And then standard prelude incident stuff.  I am a little mad that I had to add the `main=` token.

Answer (score 6):

## 196. [Cyclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone_(programming_language)), 9555 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJzKzMpESWSh96xotet8cP9nh2MPas3T3jXew8GNjBYh/W8AALrF@NgX/DN0@LwQL9D3rPORGZTF6kqvq62@sFTInMuJw4EXHixIkTJy7ZVJzeb34Txg87MvVRVzdd5qqOy9q2dqPaKbYxYs8Uzclnc6EQQtXs7qCvGq6zFgozmTHNaGlt8DPXvFYN7ZNqQ3iWMcs2u7bSZ25PcZnqtBRLdZg5cK2By8zO/GQ5xrb75pWWxJR9zegCmKvalq26FL/C2JmhK/1mW5mKyU9laNkQ77AtVf/c/@yyltnvK0bbAcgCY69M21ERvqU6jonJVxkbbqutKaRFAFVszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqFi6OmRK03FtpeVqpoE0ybCTg7OTo6kUsszenO7sTIdm2cukabCdQet6OirHzmxH0ZVp/CusNnDNPXc6PM9qXdVQWDZVSmWnIwtsw1ZmkqwyW1XaHU1XU9AgLMl6qm6pNsMQ1jFttgdF0ouZYqZRG6dMtTBtcRw5jbbE9FzOnapPNgOEN@2eakAJM9ORsh85FZH1I9oaZaDYIxZ1eqYNfGSzgaO22a1pt4G5DH0US0B6NvzEmoqjFlYQQc5HcG2YtwYwkWtC0zZHrsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZvWaDq0xF5p@/PYOZfhHWHTbENrTMXJ7EiBIMpmkvC57GQvaEHrQmdmVw4UrK0yx9AsS3V5JPCKalM0pGa6ZlzzDn5km@1BCzuf21Mhb@ywyA9OqAWpqswSYiKFDhYmDuJgUIITs68Gy@swQ4UGciy1pXW0FmcsdeiqhgNFdlJMg0rcarrO2qoOCcbYWwnmmNi846CmrvRSrVQIGRNzYf1rnWmsZVmMR0EtoEg7mSJTkXrsE8TrPYcNrT5ztD5Euy2z01FV9km1epA81DZDDD4ta6pavm9JBRhD9UijWiAQkDQmUhro5FHo1laAtLYjaOBqfSCs5kYcpiqOhgIVkjiq0SaqWr6oNZkywfLsRoMOD1Uf2ITbUW3qcoQXuqetAkrFb@bora25LvUaVmNHqmKzU1tVY5NidyJLyMzEHFysSIoadX09sn24E4HG5SlSigWNaedOX78IKSxVYUuNMnwrklQObR9ssbulS3RzKQsMYNlRJcYqPzAnfXmpwncoN9Nd@z4EWENAFZ2lTctNK0kLCph0oYBpBZ3oSt5kU5YeyJitT7VFgOU4VBtaA4QPe5OgmrUGto0jyZioyjVUWjeNLtATKmsPDKSHwQoZaIKWCQNBgqk3QDWQvNRGIBeQwqc9DRrNwSYJdCw@HhJBYUQENhYU9fJ1TH1AcJDScZGXgSqQFDHuddgb1lE0HZNAPKLipbZVZ6C7mGZgtLHlYbxT2ynmFYM6rA18fAPZKYCUAoD1@4F@SYUCYGgIk6qKUT/@0z9vd7uAp9ZqgWwT7PqGtc0WjdwKFRaGQ4YMCwJVp2IBXAJz58khgxtF19okIBRjJLKgQlCut@ZAbzMTMrRvNeilPeUGejZ0rparcibng32C9ZVrLk00zrlQ8b7ShIalDChvqnaSPduEVmqpoTDxTLI/cDtFlrS2WcRJfx99uhZ9unipQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9K60Nbq5ankwSwBzS2iwe6qRlsxKQQihzrFTboP0jwFg8ObpHAF4kyngSTH6FQgGAkzHXbDA8Kk7CBfmsggIIdSjq6qVjSTkmMoJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICq9p9XgkHIkHq04YoKYTFcXOeqqZKLZ0q4eDFhDFcCwYCWzk3RaM1CgZHc0FjTPBmsTXNIqAZCGZeKtGbBWHdJ@PqEvyLofpkygoBYZxF5rsyWo70JFBCEBfdp0Zaaybt5AhlQmHGRAdBmaqdKFpIDGvSI1XhOdEIZNV4ooGYGuqrJhsatAJsLuBTBc8H6gbgOeyHAaw8U4SkD19ZQRYWnxYHXcYpnWgL/VBPIA21FJR5oDwUfmAgpkMqP85oGOjtp1JZvP5yT4208VcO11Lvgch/Sn9aE/Cygc7Ewoa1lFvma4Y3YHSVbkmxpRWS7VcIaigJo4Lomh6vKHApBg8U04vtPRsOm8aRDzVYpwHCnneemIoVFC6CEU/CeqMyhQxVQHN0QaxpI@mcweAm6nMpQ8IMlGAD9IDRfA0AGAydai2Bi5INWDg257W6gHPYukMLhf5IDSdPQQFcwfJnuz4WWNh5OqTbCiV9oOwGA@iSGKLzuKBwRVRVScCqPGDAY9jVpz@HMSmX0QYCAKhqbSSAt77As6@aZhzkAIhfbQIMhnD2wE0sRNUKGHg8tQu6qy@luk3EbQZTgTayH8917WcNRgnNLc3aKaAU9Kn9mjPPTSQWdKuPdJck7ubutkEsexA/0x7OaRbg6Y2nKoQhflteOWEbkAB6zisAiP3xwFwXTTScUBgUvgmAgeiJBLchIL/SgBIQCkgVLTjkCjeAaFyMjJaUSlFXSkFnU5KMAk7rgTTHQlT@XTZNPsohdg5KQao6cG0TzNwriBkPol8Ze5Q58t@0usikdSVqRnRu8ji4mJkLVIFyb64@BRc6@h6iq44uJ6SK0kuhEuhi1IkyIWxF5QCw@qR@wsP8zBWx2Yb4qj0SbOiysXaWq6eUC5k8cziMwaiDiQbQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYVL2Fiqaancnab6J0PmnZmiWI8EK5UbhfUCFHZND6Fk4jbbWMg@zjNOlXbBgFQWlt9aJ25PIic1m/vLtsxy/vIwlMHSsrlSZUCvKL9lNd2xzAcBm7WFlLyvVY7CIHg2SzEslElqPRYlKHjJRY7LtiLK5wakcjKkjt6OVlBIgq6HPR6tmEb5jIxmI@qaAcODCDThiNpO6KkH8zVo/FI5A2FknAFKMSiQBlWkgEhyqNnDlBoMPjl5wwm/F4iNjQtK/xOyP2ISwFEyyefAf4d/NkctrbvwbpylqOjqpI0ubaCHjTyzywTQ9f41pje6SxGjDcQg1gtG37MyOcjRsD0p9JuTWDGdF0ECEoDMcelKvaBAwi7mhDmCBAvx95ihCO36gLbcKE09TV1DmpJhKDjoPTXjU1Vxs64sNKquWMeQD0HnBautKCjj2J7lJil4AQ@Dydnh8TK88gnlaVaFbzpTrCwNJSDKRfWyOtfaA5PSQvaFY4lbA7QFVU2UE3UIlqe6wFY34XKK0ONZfr8MBHJ5hkV3GiMdQaa1zrQmUPNQYslGcDoOHcbMF8RwXNAWP55JFtGzeabRpI5NQ2oAaGL2MbTCGfR15go1ptL7v1MH3nIQeKzQTLAdoGsU4Tt@W0WNowdbNrsmUAQNZMpThj7xloKgGdz4XpJXO0T0SgWtc0RlM8qOJw76COKBdyvvatIGSa4FNXIGvY/EqPAR6o88ne@20YIeR8JgPl93wZ@viVDGCZriMGttgYQJhsdeQbbMn3qtUbTRiUkD/4LBL4yVR5x@TzegUGVCiV6OGfKGmwk/MQ6OdeVNtzzav7NmlIaMoIzjImag/KIPRTUR3ebaCG4algDPVIMYF0psHH7bsDsvO0N1BDaqtnMukSNIxslaXb6k0aBY4Egq4HqnISslJtUsb8ZMKEHHLNAWh1bVXX@pq7R@Yu3UDVZTwse7FotRsjONJUNyTmG2Pxiiapsaw1uhx@e4gDkhNS6ckODre2G0e1092KlB44dlrXmsDBbbXRB8VTVx2JTX/C7FgFZCL9p2v92DTdCm@ua5198RPGNF7y/a3G/t7Gce34HS8EoXG0/kBXsChrS1MAmPyEor1eFbADdmyz72vkjmiIpRySXp2w@eP0VMSuYOxAWPwD4QUM76MVP9UKdVstljS51w8UgKsIiJZ9GsO68ThCkqXfDxSQRUKJ1v6U3fQCSxjo2/knLOBjdPPiH04kMN/JmXtE7hgDxwrU7E6WKfzG7XRw1PaDsxR8nURW18fBOQrm6wSTFnpBlpmoucA@vhXCx9cX5uKbiZoL7OPLc3y4LjEf3VTMPFAfWYGQ4TrGXFxTEXMAfUyrhCm49jGOK1LcQwsfIq@50Q8m8nGXCDcujoxR0VKJCPIAs5w7@nzhwmmgjXTMI1l5Ihaj@HIHS7ZhcrKOIMgvn3EhBIJAi3OsdsodumMUuSCKJOgcfBnEj@eMIOsNpQG9clxaLyQQxZI6CDC5ME6c9xObU0lNbRzsg/N2zeoNEAGDQJf2QoJRfiLehN56S7BTZHkL2qY1CvTluywnfl8T4iTQu3Kc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vzWUijndLvs7SuOLGuoZYZsF24YLwFIbefRMUpn3NodXPoGQM@Yr9ZUjyZicTarg0jsmOrYQseTPfvCkFEZHMBrF6beKkeOxqZFJyHrH4KPrX@mzKDuiW9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvSbHfqZA7AmLGcwLOJSEFLlBVr/0bhngqav3hIY2QAIGVBLM5T0MT3QGjCvPJN2jYnCNNXOAJTgNEzS0P0FsGSpSJCdZlN7CBTogkX3nnPA7EFzHtmgt/ZmTF9sgvDuwHZ1tS2e//FnbWiA2ebpKSNS/H1HA@hGvNF5sLVEUvTQz/yWJZirga4pRAZyfQllS8HVBkX3HfNRowbDksmeYvdRvxaNC8yJP9C7HuEzXnJb1Qdt1XvOz4RIPGlg46kNrU81gidOEGk6/EDyKfMgT09TLN1U2oSFT4Q0ddzavF3UIZ8SBDRtkEVfUU7PisfGy2Zub@AO@C@ulH2pXTULv/OpsjbJZJm80pTVtOkoTU19hA9s5XrQNpPWdZcqjUUrPMTtvBOh0SnZ0ZVr7mygcz4BeBVtrdtVbe/5ENhtD3R7mpSkb@nxCKt4mhUjXVl5DKet89@HQLy9Kr7jYTppOv18C0MSi7Sg1yBpcTk8GSCTNkVYXWmOcHLW@3bOwgxJZQXBU2nF45kcjrH@2sd44d2yHk6PAzOlL5Xmp@YL8Zwk86Ysab4An@SGKaqzWJL/Qq@HkUvrK3oy2w44HxTintFz7JoDSjP1ZEtXHGAmVzSHegPNRz@PMTgORi1kq7HrEfYeF8dbAntoNWWcxgJNRNcci/c44XlImk7bocdocEcE/YyTom@Wvm1Shp1e0nfNFwhmy8UVjQf47SsEHF9MwOWaAAOlzIdo1zJv8fugitEzb1T@O3/Q@zS3VF8hqpI6cYbWmpO83foSu@KaOP3Mp@L13FK5LX1uuLDcT04HvpahHU03HZiX4@9jhAAN23H473xWDtJMU4wkGZiD7vnJRKEslhIGtQdaUtG7pl4odtMK/DzY3AO7g@JfPL9W7PliS5a/LLY87cg0ZPF8UN5fp@3rL3ECWaFtXK0KOB8ZbOfJLrHK8XAFYQ6BS9DzK7eTKVLKVJobSR5qALvVu1VG3vMnDCkPUdcbUqwR6dag/GGCUhEcrs317Z@S28rjubW/TiDNoF39UiUCjXutqyCe6XemSVk2I39jCjmT@Xrx1NEH6kCdq@UdNq9U3ITIzbm4c0HRdb4Merp3@I2FyohqLAlzYhqIh8ZEH@qTmDl@Valx8EbfowJG0TXo5F9UcebKOwsUcgsn20fgOELHbMKuMbAmGjdAu@OBcfw45XqW17PN9kQhMeZbJVLxy4rUhM7uqPR9SL/f7pswPzb7oDAYX9H@AilZPvjvBGIKGasZEwaSudn7S9qg0ILiAS2qXTtJtI1/ndDJPjSpJ@BSCaZthuqO8PchSs8Tok3T1L@lZUCWtjXabKwncXvpl1poRskRuxvY2HzhoCmk2XnIcMHHGTHDBOrhbNp9ZP4cNEc9MiWcMa0/MloFDO1fmmTCSE2WIcduee6HGPIYO7WcKqZWH2VHroOaTVVX@GNYWHkMXymVexSfr3UI5ZYWZnAxhy/fjNe/wlOixxoBsbQ2TFB6al8l7yOavdK@Gjje40GgoYnfOdGpNC1GPJDO0qCvG/g7sVQU0IZc04AplavYXRXnJDquYYrQh@Srt8Yxl7h7faWr8rMIj4mOsWkCt73xmdzYOd9IscZ3orQgGV@of5wVoONcqyPHe85F@GrUgvYc9B/FNq@Pt9AC@sVOnUrPXdr5grpn9Mye0VN7NnUO3/dQ9wCOdPkpkscqAeXvKc417vMjeTSey/WcIHV1U9e/hrooD7l0NM35xtlt3KPfhqTfhHekNCFCPL5ox4Mhm4hEY/dDfaenDmBkckzXtNQk@R4C1dHiw3/n25v3DiMOO9dUu803KaD5T3G1pq6yWw2KcOUEV8bnW5OauqngVtJHlHegjPf8GvtUy7S/aPzoKqZrWfRoWPrAoR@y8yY78w2Ya2yHSvo1zKC5fH8IZ1m1azZbPe1LRWqqimto12nPkMO9j85LhTCmmmssuYXBKV0DWtmjFDJBJRh/go@9h8a/wDLO3NpvDmx79GXBMLnq79tb@SoBOh7KXyzQzommIR83QHkbfR5ZqhDruQ9yEynQqCwn1QxoJfKD9p@JvV5CetHC4gNKz1S9qTCBtbRvsV@KDQFkydMCmxogfJ7x4iFBuCvkG8wKo7uDrhP7MuP22qBT4c9chLUuHqviq0mObt4GrM3Q9RVDPOaOyv7K42MLI/lHV0ZSabHemVQHD9q2dM1y@C9LdrJzscwu4M9CjebPdEXztNUO//2SVtc3bdzsDupDsmWrTgtN3ih5uUTk4sYwuyCBkzobA3uwc4s/u19gnl4yObol3x6oXQU3v@1ruA9Od2YHPMA8vXXgaxC/HiiO9npguupcnNNbCL4G5Sulq7V2J1rAQ@hRV@yU4o@JDoBBsw1x29Mc2nPsOeZ3Gs5itBo/GzltVffPvj1uBAnoRGLrJ0vuMW@LqO9Auz7GK3PzmtQ4xUL8g0JOc8lYKp5z6zl/u8VjFoTbQd8aOOIxP/c@niAI2oz71xTu3GogAZMfQeCynqK78@3KAcMp6FJiFBw7H9Kw32u62WXvixkGqhcIN1S4H2CsDRiTjxQXeoDhzNP4aCaUTeXxMO2XxrnppUy0VCS5iuN8BNZQcyypGZr7uFXGdRWYFXlPrCJXvPDMTHoff1PPvhVD8nQ@nfYfrRQM8KOWDvOcx6D45otjOv3nnxNxEmJ7I4Rptjik5qS8k6Bh2gpKp0a8UwQsjGdZBjjKuaadYgQXjSrxeCwW4olwnaBrAJgHRWfx8JwOP@bnMF1zXILVOuzigi3dDdcya/I9qzBpTWL1OseKHzo1sj206CDdMU9@saTUK0uRZDKyFLk01lgm4oOrOvSZueDKBGxHowcv75gEzFD4hl90ezUu83NITo/O@IFu2AYd88wg0w/qq/w0DT@qdYobFP7DX7XF0UeYiDqgnMGYBQTBk79mX@2Zt095viL3mmUpeHQScYCI0/lBnuRmjUHfA2WUn3g0b9nZzmlRnKMSx4zBc8SVFb8UvHHRHIK7oF3eeLw0/o5WkbGfyqtUy9QHfQPU/7bbc1LsRKMNzgN7vFMRXAhmuDbOgdoJtsfaKi4D0751mvbrpnlNB1CwJP/hr/jpMdq9LnYVe9nTqdFAjrhJXaYjW62WOYBSe0g@qbYpQKJIZBB4AzSoMeR4Co/hnm461gYcmfQOdVE2/GTXZu2EJbdZBE9Q41mRstaJLtWOn7@5yNQrP7B@Wv2PP0vH7gThpO@SpYIjJZgHUr5HxgpG5yF6HBth0tJQ4hn6W/s1sbX/lrcHkEjhTIa7@z0eM01L9Bo6mEvnUH1uFBdERNFN7eyd7urTmV5iWPWWTnfRlloDBwI8LGs40MHAGyPUvNdVlqIDbvdJnrgsDxniCTkFXPwUMG12x5NKmGRpyD6zHjJZsoUbsMHHCanj4bh@ZcPbF5QL7t5Kb6nNAW1ZuMmmsrkKVWepUVmvkstW2yYeUr34/nKYzSQvh6vb9bTjEfXycvhdJvsWqG7ClHTpSRp73vbB1t1Sqpr5/NlRRkyS7iNlvtsMxMTS3dHe0fbJae307ARa4d4TPzum3VfGsga5iLZU90ydjv8CXWxNdb5B/vg@AI9G2ZLC1vFii1gsFNwtTKCC1lJSWuLOgGiaSP2F5PPSO2ogfhZAyLSOxjyO2oNhANsQmA2phpUfWHiImYm04iAmcZmGMh47kE8Y3NM3R5YSqSRWAWIlgVhfSSr2cGWf8rCvodgXsTxOtqdzQZBifn4Xfjyv4lwS3P9O6m3BQPnb15tjebzeBPNIvQHUD/XS7NT29s@OtyeTAY/Rk6RupZQX2@S5cMaexk1G3slTOlEkEqLNrCIxiRJwrxjM6NaSpureqlAtIRxbfZ6YOJTKL4XGjAmUqeDVL/Uyp0U0SiVAHaSM1Zraxd/RhoEiemN0AN0dr6IvBHYkH7VX8JQkMIfpGo4UfrxqIFZBLq/rHZEQF/I64gTVn4TX47BqOEaDSk6pHhiq/FHHYfAfGJU8V7bOhkwMZ3KdJVkWvroK09GeDxsr8zGKLXFCSEu87JJfXrwCAsrUvlJo@ko7ysRBBRildcXC8@YC@gCmjGvs48CkU1GeMPH1i1ucHCn8thNq2paCtaHTVoaLZ8e9cYvw7e2cVFA746oZyfcgzw0MHKgAKHD3yPYQ5j3AbB2S9fwWA05yUxyY94ZKsmU64oCsryU47EZzyNaJjdBBHUcHSYm1ERXHi3/oPByr6Q7oJG0Yvvk1OaScpGjXM9/6nDSYFAaeTPkqY4JJIYR1KrMHqGEovW3BsPqBJ14iOMLsBHBG1heTSaBcVzO8i2rW0CRLtqo15toD3DhQjcwk8YqwRq5kz@3rAcA5V0lcqukf/@mf8@sjLl1w/0K4h5kN8P2R8HXA/U@8GFkG3z/zfVnw/TH3fZ/GJps9My@yFzbTB7eIA18@k2bqhDLBu62H6uK3Nrb0m70j5pDdGNuyrwwDzYQSBnlOM4BeWh@Y4obaGMF5DuMmHOOJXrwBFgG@Av5A9QY1GspPtetRPDm9lk5jwXGCm6KdxuqQG43pIPXHAV4gAkpYupAvrMhpKGTyxkNIpxm7uLWVI4zF1kAmhm40q/Kh2cIDC0xyWoquVgplzhvpJeX7nPTBL@gSwIb4ROGCQRo84@CngLiqSBZdUuJyDJPiQBaRIyjT2iZnNdAGo@QAkBgGG95xMFA3TUEq4GNDHbqkMY28CVATL4pCg5fKr5HxECUBEceN11xMd8fxZlXc2x/ooKlgM0jnCHaCYGvSPGa9@J5dupdGXVx3woDxfjWHdQ1w/@M5d6BwzsLznbOXb0Snr87A2rBnJ4aJm5p3oLQsmk1nc2m5EAtwqCRQQXmxq38GlNC5QVi0VO3KtJza5vbei8Ojk5lLJAgyMg0WYZHqevwymUpc1H1HxC/3JFE3dtInrzZ2PFIGSzVe8keI8br/dDHn5TZd0gdyP@e7hGfzpoiZjOTM1yKmRbbkDm2LmcU@jk0HADf57sSZXKOxu/uL@nr10gjPZP953sU64dQyMhe4Lh26VicyXUws4p639/kUL@xzUt4ZmKw0vjbKP7nD/ePgh6@B8K//G98F4e2yDtEpTf@QZij1wP5rqHsqzbOiixB4wbzygqzxiipjUccZtkIz2zaCpWGiLrM3FYpjSD6RDrkNybtnzuGQDglnbmWiC1l8mvlwpx5G7Prj2xnEtQQ9KJ2uNUO34gStd4jLPz2bcixdc6OxkCEgpo9zzUI6j15y4IMplYsh888lOagzDlNk5ovSHUK39RC/I4J5VznE6TaIowHQ7ci02NiKtqV6rmPQqdjWALJo4YTsxaAPcB16HKs4WqigZSUhMdAz4hXlAu8/EJRI9dv56DCW6qnDttaFEScaS4Bo@k6Wx/dIKHgRAuhVzXk1QLOU1VOgDtg0uXW8hmEYWy@Rd1xBbk9kt/ODjXoIkGHSZmyNWy4iZ4Z35Q82/BqLJHzKNGOJSIrxmZS4zYeWnskQlWKbPdyoR6aPTkcjlS14OpsP5h3N7qewVjDMcBZ6jtt0g1zzTVd6BCijXCgpzWirwyienl6rI50gPHJ7fhOJSTMsTveKiFsk2tMXjHiyUHGFUBpfzjEl70olX85NioZSKdVzQnjCDSYlkOOJa@@DE1SEaKevWCw6oBtaHJZi5I1eRo2E49oxlqzicH3LDBaPk00DHhQBcxYE7ZBLo6PwUbzQLJquQCNhqGO08fFJs9iFnErVwU2ZxNgS2jM3QZtCS2AsBHNUSLJGaEG/gL81LBG/fjIlrqFcomxDdEkCQM2NJjnV7ZF8AVpQrVn1yfhEekDAcKqWSmuiNSalfYkBX6zPEYiAdo4U9@YIQF9xRgmohjIaoDZtta2BvHz2UjUMFQgEPNPH2zaVATCZHUt4F8Emxhe1UQ5hXsRdcegJCjp5gdt25E43QV1bSpfJNFa@B7XmwyXqNR2h2YzS/206lS7fRZf0yigNumasGl3qVeR4bjkeXzKWo0sGaltPnqBF7X4JlLlGCiaoQwBKLumxMvAzKH@VJaO8pKxHl9qV7DKlAC9Mke8gwQ9OOnW3pNynl56AspSAEJsLneiSQ3erZFIp@R7Khz1kKZ0AnrnDS0LoelfMfkmLx7EMqaUGFuCH9OVJnIbNy5M0Ge/KYi6Q7vZFd5tSxfyWmLmWlhNQBK/5A1YeByyxd63hAY@vb8vNi3tA/eMZv8Qdvow2JqhOcPIlTcZ8vWARchplrhAyUX65DRBwGAUiojehxGIgTH7zm7BcYEx6WshFzfjTfKYcj@RlmKbD/Dr8DPTw9LJkS3eXW8kbpiYjFx0ln/pYP7o@Onobu4yyEouENw8leUX6npWy7Os@qyz7wIf9Np9weDkdCqeX5Ser6fSHDx9gxgGfi2qqCuKDf2IXyUj9IrrKWHV1dTlRKC4nnkUagYLFotls7ISl2aWmaZbTbsPX7NFdzNEw/zx9SnnB9B/@GQ8T@QuH50EQERr@VjglH2aXq4qyHF/JPjPKULQSfnJMBif@FuErs3yebePnb//3v/2zv/0T@vsz@v57hV2zT/C57jD8J/endsCtoLvZ@YR3z8DUokJywYpE8rnIyfcR9p/ts8jk6tPV//Qnhx/DbriaTZ/b8HTDH8OFYpg7wQG@nOe7CVfD6whWuA@P0pVKBZyr/@l/hfTVF4AHY0br8FPNe7gKo3A1WaEkn8PVAjjkbBby/b9/9rNQuDoMfwrLshwe0V8jnJHxU3wiP2EMHGlptSiZ5jOvvMPAxwtLy3L2ctyegebGpvWDe5APtCszw5Og5Pa5igluIMe3wOFtw4XFZx@2GFNhqMXP2tqzGYLvT/mPU0n4pEQ3GKInOfSqEC5WEg2evc@r4YBjqsL@LxN19/3fCBcKe1dmJi@UTn2C6pdhubhy@Gz41R82LrRHxPCYdn7mbDrMo7rvYV6nZ98CFwr/UKkcu/j3qol/Ryf4x4Y/5QOon8JnEf7oHz6@F38XKUQEE8jsZ/G36K6h8EX4ol5/3aM/G/92DfxrfsS//U/499rFv9MW/h2/xr/T9/jHZioTCq@vr4fj8WNQDQXPfs3nDL6pVEP4PN5FdL/TD1s5LBw@C7Fwsh5P3t9fpL4fxstl8Q9KU9n34Ye7oFj1@2Ry/ftqPH5BxbuoinKuJ@tVKCsvMv18vw6I4@sX6@upRrVaTda/r16sTyYS6Z49i2M/fQYJq/WLi1D4Dtuigj/L@NNy8DcrSWny4mABo3MJXIyc9BABjG7LR38o/GH9QzT@NP40o2duMvK1fP3KPBz/Hx4OIUIbZq5MO9PL9OQ2SESWUc8yo8xomOmbh3IbnCr8Zfrg1DKdYaabMTKGLI@GE6ge/u8fmu6rQxOwmZDSHWZcRJzpwLN7ePgK8HUg7yv40zKZzBAKOczcwH9GR0FNF3HR8/tG7DJ0waQPKoz@KTmSykRShUhEq@cL1sfLu/ts4aOUiDQuLyL1cjjtXF6muXbEsitluobt/r7R2D7YajTSyEfrS/Fn8eQz@FSq8XXxeBqulp9eriWx/Tj/pRrh9PrTy2ouie5CHBopC2Hr6fg3fsYo4VldvAzBhO/8HL/ntze33EUOcl2en/ux@JPGIHJREHwAND03/YSDgab5e/pvH/6X9f/qjEUv6jHGonf361H6xPAvFru7v7sXv9VYNCo80XX4wwDwY5K7@yo6CegOXBfRWD12f8/D4DcaW@cIq5jHepUSjwGhw4Z5rpeRMmh4laWoWFS7vBxmMrFyE0J887rymdZnYmXaubLUxDU1mA3IyzECya@UyyvCvVosl4vCLRcK5fKyD5UBj3ACkOoorTIyejkcwyJw7o9m0KZCV11Gom21g3eeP7UsmNjJpcznz35Qo9HW7EYDw3OfP19CR4rgvpVKKQ8hmeLnz9AHIzGY9B2YYsW0BFM4OZ1FpwzO/Pp6YaVaLayAu1CMxcrSEt/MEu3GS3Lsfikt8dLBNCsSFlFycTVGofcRjGfhdfa0Cozr4Ifd3YeJiGwlH4s2R2qMrRSixXhJ/FUWY2w9XV1m4u/iIhdfWV5dflavjwch7OvlO6Ui31fulDWc6d@XW@K6SNwYqDx5kitB7YqZ8mWo0diqndYaeO@@JKEgtRjDUBIbIVwitOzIBdll8qX6BRa8fhmJrJWf8eYp5lk4UhZwyQgIIFYsUf3CMPnTOrgleIjyWXzX5OVsbjGdH35X2M6Asvx5GT8XFxfFbDG@DAJquVSq1@sU@nmR0lz0h5063UhUSV7IhXw9iVrI1bCzDIWVV3Ph5ZBFG4JWM6yNa6o22rkWIbCnOKyJy9@OquveFZ23pq23b7W2CtiP9mub26eJ7DqgzO7UNhPZk7ONsIze/NhP0Tn0H2/Xtg7PIMHR/nbtZPv53pvtsyMId2CsA2LBp3@kqAO1od4OBrfob6j02dQc5epKsayGBZ9h58df/fzHX/13P/7FH//4Fz//8S/@7Ne//LOfw/ev4PvH/PnH/7aUx99f//Kf/c8//uu/gMB/D99/B9//49e//Bc/41/y/w18/89A2N@IbwCOf4GUgO2Pfv3LP/nLX//yn/xL@P4r8f2X098f//R/4///l/hD51/8@Kd/gz/C8/M//vEP/@THP/yDH//wFz/@4T8E5H//17/C/z/567//d7/C///l3/z9X/8Pf/9H/xM5/pw7/p9/9W/579/9wc//7g//@d/9wS8f@P35o7@//IrwX/4eQr6@nF@D52vq9a0hv/xJ5fltqDHOhRjsz/7xj//iHwHn/in3/ffgg38/6he@x4@J0wwtGR8H/oKxz2nQgTLPPvuggPJ/xFAIZp8nsVFoxgv99S//@V9i8ATsPwpiyMizsEsI7Of2C4D9137BgrC/@PFXP/vxL//hj7/68x9/9Uco0JIrpUQtkZS/YMsBwPxXwCFg4WvgAFBex2XtRbYYyoJjcR1tDyE5/uEDkHQRXKBLL4fyOfCF5Cq5ZXRDQpiaLPPJcRyn/PAdhlZK4ENrQByGkDiPikPURpxVKpV4aFiBOAIFL6YZsmoR5z@o/lcALybiaRKNIqiWbLhBWCBlJX7MGsuVIU8Yx4AqYWBYIAw6luSsFC9WtiDDynCLIS5EHg99gOeHSrVYGVYR3Q9UBMAR34AsAaqCpRtWfwB/hXACfGi49QMUpViJx6tFCKlQVSm3RIPylPNUOap7nFG9MZwxNIY9fcbYd5JclPg0DEjJBDT@xsfQT8kY8RTiL@PLojr07znpu4zpoZ2GRB8exuOfYjClFwCAN5nELVDwTSaxNM8geshRxSlbeMQ5BqBcXFht/AAaZeOhOLVvnDyQP5Th6z7r1YAH0WF1lpaWwLVelXLSIejzzL5ec1zFxhUCUmnWmFQoSRiMO0rUpSPS@Je3luFXhv/tRdoVysmxHFqK4FAeYV4eyXjOXDHDVHqvalSXZSp5nOBC4XE41zJpmQfUwxUWC0XpzukYTRtVCzSY0Cunu2EOQRVMSFJCLpS4tVTMKt@Za2uVH@SV1RA8yT/A667FxcvQDPgKpBT2LiRo9S65Tj0NnKBuFELVqliqYnKoerJ9CglOD5mczaQY6I93K6vZlfxKPpsrFPKrWXmlUFop5Is5kFCFTD6blUsrK6ViafUeCvQM@nlibbmZX6/@g5nPf/MP5n3mh@InVH3Lhil2dPQ6eR@qDpPJdJaKXJHzq@VRBQpCQaEqaVJcVR7dJUHpxOYJXdKuqDvcgANFC90lkVUX4MNCCyG2AEHwAcxoqGdi9XjvsCyW0fBlAnwpTZLzwAyx0CUwA8cWsgKfELbbExA2T2TuzBfGzgw6T/HIzAGgh1Yw2D7uVnRNdmryXXEbaiu0Lo52VEMhWnK4AJrWQ3hR90U9tJ72Y@dj2uzx12tt2iZoqD8dZkMxrnnUloZX9LVcP2pXwTt4nL7m9h6AOLP6eJpEtX9vGLb7TSggWhw5wAb82LppzgNYZWdHD9TylX8ED9fu6AwegB/vPd89DTxPt2ubu6EC2zg82Jp65AVQnu1v75z63lUe6yXN@yjebe/vT3vFA2cZiyy/mkiAeIQffCboQ8/U0vceiJx6eNzMJFhjpDZVvIH9hN8xP@zopiNHIl21D8MbdGAZ39vVNXWYRC1lNjO4pJD@jJOghprNj9gSiMISTATZer5aCEt5qVgpZLIw3NC99x2jHC7AlPCiVLfCzkq5lJPjx5ZqOlF5NbaaKeVbtmpWNgZF15WeSjDXDL3CbV8lmR9f0JzQLkxm@ngVOB4hd0O22oaJza1BJzOa@NqdgcUeDIQHBqHT1ro9kJK3pg8Ac8xQU1EYfL/1AzjU4Md9PMDleVDYTIw@Cx669a1DvtmH@fYfITzOce8wnRvyFplpJHLWQqcos@ltTAwPxzXxBQZ0VAuUAX5Cl143oIIEL4VCuLCmdVgmlCJzWbZUzBdLuWwxUSwVV/Iwx8wn5GxCXi2uljIJOSMX5UIxX5ITxZVSbgXkN8TmS6uhMMg4rZNOw/AkSxI9NaOFF4au482rZqpXDYW5uQF0Anx/XVjxAwZFJuWKlxlIJ@Hd7Y5LG2mXtYqEr4nM4EsYZSkkKazFwjs7m5mdHUnaQA8aCDczktRGT76YyaxuSJJKMZsw0GQlyeRpIArAXO7JZDY2JWnAEeA5R8DdQ992AVViSdLQs1nb2cGMrtCTRQSA4ZrHcI/ueVYBzEBPLkc6tSR99NEh8hrPaoXKuo0ezBVR7PCYTYiTpOdeiTIZQHHM4QSKXa@6tZok7XFPrYYoXlDd87ywL9FTow8kssEH3C9JXXB0bZj/S1ITnNgHJKkFrtZIgbA@uPBopOEqkjTiREIySdKQoJXWtQQqoAiHfKA8u7tKz22rXf4Z2fzZgqg9iNKGg@2d5vPnzW63aY9q28@PKerFi13lajSwm92mSNhswMfEVBB13R9Nf1SMajQUfX7US4gypqIao4ZKJWwoH6Fk4tPFjPqNFxj1AqLmrcAIhPDpA3ATPxt9eG4oTR7lfSiKnsNmUyoj34aw/wwTowu5XnZHlormHgzqKy3bLNMv65PcjcbuMuV7jOtE6c0PKMRjd6OLYSVTh6mBXEb5Gl3sP5XkUl5aW1SeRofoLkhrMDlYkWJrKLHNToRFkvLTQVEqrEpry/AEIZoD5zCaiWQYg5/YxWr9qbQKSKSnT5MSlA18JfCtrkoxXgZUW6BEnegwAVlDYDq9jkIBuzE8QUsSKs6pOnRTuypuCWklk@cTn/X1c4DDQ6F4ou9g0Gcb7JbkEO7v97Y4NyobIHQyZQPPm6voXRqGh6FqW3EVmOxs3A3W1gTsfblbuUAEn/FnPSmdV8@lOgvmm1/NQKnOjFZ2dX394nMdND0g3SgMI1W2WB6G6QjH6ko5ChOLWMVRP3J977OOFrrFRiXDNb8lZ9C/yCwW5MRdspG81xXHXZJXs2sXg6WLpFxfXMx87q5L76tSHbNHhZD@gmZEkI5lCPNIxuVpuKN9gHi2luTvyJCLhVgKd5o3zE6D7sFnHwJic5zQKsPYraugwMilbFmAhKwKb/OoxKL4ghu@5SUaiaxmI5FYpAxQixAsWpMYKAJNHnkiA@eATFuTSlmIt1V3ADoN8J9XTL8EXA8uyKHwfaiNt5@ulELhu9D93f161VMZXrLRSIknPe8TxrpxmBKlaYEDl0YWyZVMVZ@xWqXWPa6VBWhtkyYuwFCX/CBVMr34rcso8fXq9/x5iUtokE2IE4dWGtPr8Wq6Wq1ehiRJCkueETxazMNsB00CP4Tp7jq2edcZGHSmfe0VkktZ48rPRT32w4Gm3xVzySpp01HoDffh@Hoal@dS1TQRq3VIi9ehsGEKJ9pSXegcUVD48xJOrVRmnZS@X/2@@P2rs8Ozwx32LLNWXCtyStBugmeJhByRI0DZZzCAasfbobD12czLPxgvyuE1K5JbieQmlLXLijhGHEU@iF7gogF86xcwbarHwFWpZJ/KhewaaFbhKh5mzK6Gq@SQC6vhepgnXoHYOt9BlpXD1bQIllflWNhJch/wcz7sQOMXX334DNNd8epNLUuudFqUaOl@/R7@q/cXMCO8p4nhPf3jTxp@7jkA/CO47@GP8ScAF4QZx9d/SK7z/3X62TzkhZYKQO3wh0oVGvX7xveNcChcilTj6Qi@RlpseRBzLdSrlg36U51l/Pt@HLAMquCy7wPv@jLLV2XG1OV0On0Ze50FtahUKhQL4dBvZj/pZZgVLi/UWIRfAcPVMXqfundWJjLxDi@czC8vJLdODjdfwpwZ9DHVwHcZss3DgxRG4ev2xoedWrqq2PpIvG9vhFCoxp1uHuEbuc@2jijNOR1zo1Cas4tclvbaa@J1F4kbJqdyLJvJ5NOZlbScZ3JxLbO6li0wBcSNg8fahWsJkzKq1qZpjbjyHN2MUeKFGsJg3L4GkyBHXWPPj/YpBZ14X17Y2n51yA4P9t@lvFAefrq7d8JODndOz2vH21CPV9snTKqdsL0TiZ3vne4enp2y2sE7BtHHtYPTve0TRJAOoajC4ZQTzNcs2bozctI41jqkXk4EO2brWnUnwxXbUtJ4o@FksIHvOFDxavDJ8IEBM8l2UHM9qS3A3HLQwrcQt66VdtsO4fk6rcUWUGFdWFZt3IQq9TLOKssP3n7K2PlF1lo5iKyyVubAyK2vMj0j/pi@0s8ds8XFxUtD8uV8sBq@4hwMwp3ZEDYu09777YVoYYUtg6acXYmNYw4OjxYynm/h/Ph0QfbjjrcWsr5nb2ch53u2wbfi@3bOtxbyvm@j9nKhME52sLmw6vu2tjcXir4PmHShNMZ5sLUgZ0IesW5Mrb1A73GK7uztb7NlAIqVJ2LRioKOqWAgRHRgOPyyAyQ5W16@7ZkJ0rSaoynotvolaA98AmoB9ZELpGs9wZZNC376ar9MGh5tluZam91tJQRWvO8DRo/QXWgBK7SAFQL4BTxmi3BsscKyMQbRCx2@MBzlt0ElmHTm0GG67xy2jlpBFZghQReI0KFKSKGK166FFu4FymiHLE0d2ilKoDKUVLKlWAxPYh2c7e/zzCzIwrSjEkEy8khzcJoWYIMqwi9WHUJ54/BmobZAWi0I5QFfDRe6n2jN0HRrIimgngsLLUAwSd0bRU8wVLMSuFSJeNHDd3gDMESDOwMufgQtGm1hXbuq26ICxZCY24c7vIa42Flhk60cY5gpUYqi@d7xz5@Z57t0J732pNeIcNwCOS8Wx8dLWkHYGIYteGf/CILOOVPKBeSYeBxSQ3UoLlCvBSA6fPmxaK@UVcgoE2FPnlA51sFXilAWmC5OObIkgiACQTAiHyLzi7ZIxY0tpJdxRwF/rzISEccRfsFgc@Rf6QCSdbqgU63q90K/ORcM1XHLUwJZRHXa2NbgzmUb4EfxCJycYE3oJgnmRcoFjMQZRYKpCdaB4CmZ2tAM4FzVHstEjxWgM1LrH2zxFuL3l1A4D6Aag9xbowYDYfEEuy8x@sJC01aV67IHBfKQoIBvkWmiSAgO93i64y1Ktsz7C7Ilpv6alHs7ax4f8dTADoLTiKw4X@G8IqpLgdUx0Ax@gQz7bwXQc5bkyOJxAeFzmQDbnoRLJjncvceXX6jE9nQtFr@5FiiWH6zF9ldW47erBQxrYxaBWoCIjwLeOEDTz2RrZuehgLGQUFBtfhoKGEDHvAR9fALBV6SHIXecPvnt6WGQXpvuytBvoQW5VOBJJr2tSW970ovdF0IUBlOC7Ar7zJrokgvgwqPHrAiONpeVkwk7k14yOFSY6qXp@BKY5wA8h6KSgyEDzgpjlCApBy9DV/r4Qo4Kq@009g62TydjEV/KaYiC9/Cd1JRHbBJMFAjjnSh6Yn6Joh0kAtc3o0c8jwTRs3Fyerxde5WA8sXY@rgHTOsA8CN6wkQN7r0cINRQWzAetxMselJjyzH2BEuWYMImgJ6vzkI3HRVQPZhje2BlKasMB/H9kz0pjD0yNCcrKcqiMfb58hKG1Mwqk/vW51w/Z6zm2myUW0Vll@PxdRAh5T0Bc8C7Jlc2EBLYU8HLM@ZmdpXJsBU7x1y1Bxr3MGPP4qd63ePYRsOid0DSMmlS5pTpteYoW8R1EjAuTqo2j2uRNDYiH2AodmMIw@GcrFpx0s@RPSnWU7B4Wdrqt5blSxrtZFmSvCzrlOlsGX4jDHswXQpNHYKlWzlMy7UUPCcqIg8ttJkcYZAdCnFbSuBypqiJr0FwY2t0qQbKlEYDL7lrNKKOqnfw3cgDuwVDPqrLjgDDD8ameCR1JHRMRgryoP40GdHW8Fwn3k4Io84UQnpFc4WugotSjqGQXzLHVS0qVaAYaA7Dd4QGM8TX3Af90Kx43ipQ4tia0Ip3FOwPHrKLift0OI6B00vMCQbxPBvqs@mcOJ9t5sThtWnzknjngOfEXQ3680oAguGBGHGSb06MYR7OS8CvoxlH1C8CBLwIErhej8bmNz30q8kWD9wnRPQ/tQequBxn7zDAgqBcCg4MtHV4SwWmbWl4ufQ0Iv8sMaSMDmOBY80@W8XGnKQ4LU2bRu9hEojoXB7dn8yGa/iW@eF3crYYSwQQBjDifXd9RX8IJwsghRLOQRLmrwNnnpXT8VEjC07jHadP4al8ow3Tu3EC03oEHmPHsNj4HvACXqjkx/jMPKfLjdGtzTIOhaMVHptfnrh66iForxJyLEjQ3zb75Ldmnwzkj33yJ2VdYReT5ajHA/41CBjX0evgPykjr9STucW@qcZBrlHV6wfYF68ICWTDrwaYzNZHIySQz1NeVQg9BnylkEBcQUTfIF@o@cTB5Xmpx@PPcoUlZT8Nl3jj3kBm9UDhQ3ipQaOBt4E2GnQNXKOBlqVGQ@I50MCLA15w0BWdjcelQEttmBQblZKKlJCSydrJ5t5eUjOkBL@ztyI5rmmrDbzNSUq0YaJUkUhgNRCmp@pWRRIbuBSHUWrp4TxqgTyggl/OhIB4LvQK9@A1n1/OrhWskvkVVTKnMhtfPfgVuR1TbnjK@rGcbH6Hl5fRJl0zhfd22aqGgobfRixesIv3MUxcA4AmfVEEnq9Dlj4HL1/gRaJHA8NEW@MtBvQa4woja5/kXUsizdwiIno7mnoQwZhTOfdJR/S@EkZXVLVVoWeReSglja8nFAVLiZoG@N1T0PitDuMBbfKqElHehGebdNCMOVXUsWAxLaz8hYQ3mUADHJkW/Pq3mYDbv88E3HijCQZ5og7ceJ0JpugIh7jZBFx0twk8gb2l8VWKfWWo9QdouAmelxea3LhYOORjTWjUp8hJ6ccpihApHe@kjQq8sbi0JkHVHbpHZfouFYSfd51KrB6aFbJ0@S8WM6A6zEM694KWWOJ30EgBRQxFsyNKA2kTEpO4EkJp5bU6TD4DvOOJGFSfp8JMbvVERFCThJ9@PF4FrmOpTEwvkCIweeCFGSfgVqbge8FIuY@t@SrIuMWCUFxxm1Nu3ID5YMGDGDxFLRZ6ZCb1/5t5UrBJ/gudKv1/Pymamfr8nqcyj0xhvnm28jucFvxXhf6/KvQ/QaH/nWnzD6jk0yhne/yUuv5FNfzb1S@SeSMYNuzuDZresj9FD/sdKQKr36QHeKW@kB/TBb48PntossFh/SeO0qHfpE/bhfMds1arnfZl@/h5rVvr1Y7fgX8jsx8/v1rZ2LrdeL7Rrm1tdV90Nw/U18Xayr718m3x3fPOp48qaO@7hy/ef9KtVi/09ti6PVePbnNq0akNBh/3dkfu7sZZf/Mk/271NrOt5zsb6sct3dl6dfr25enz/En89uOLoxef@pm@c9TJKKV@bvdV4c3m6NwI5W@0s/bOvnbYP2lvn2X7@1vau534Zmb/pPRazuxv377Pbd7G85n0nvXy8Pnx2VVz@71@vLf/rr350VQKH69vrb10u9TZvDp@EzrMvZZ3Px4edrezpee76dutjtXOZHd1O3/19vho4@zdbu@lst3fyZ@V3l6Njgq9169v3IN4d@W8MHjlrMSN2uvX2ZfG85ub7eNQUzFP7Zx6br6WrdvbI7PUX1VfHux2@69t2Ugf5t/ET/qnt1vbG/rH1WHu7N3569uVk3eDV69fvD/MaCcnzW2lYDXb2ZOr05VQq5/bi9@cbZ8Vleft89f9m73d/Lut9KueelBrH@nXz7u7782To/29Ws4ZGPL@5o3@7nnv6tX11uaebh5d60ZtJZ3XT9vvDg9DZy@05pa6@9Z5UbvqvUvnN65X3sXb1vPTq0@96xcbJ2eHxezwaJQxN53j5m5nuHVcyBbTLf3j8aeO@Uo@ex0v3Fy9yGrvap/cUO7TKF/a19@pfeNFvNV9P/yop@Nnsrz5fu/Tu3cnuzd2s2acfXyzc3xlv2obh85h5vjFy1dN/broXlnvjZMTuZV5rl6/imeU0PBs14E2Uk@V/Oppf/@1NdwyPx7vvXcKn@I359c5dev6@E3t43GmeWtYbw17X@tvZtqHSu2N6W4Phs9bpZuz6119/@Oh8y70alvO53fMjrPRebNSept@Hu9cP3@7IZ8MMwfGcWelYB@8eX2uadu9t2efjlv5nTdWse8a3defzvrb8e39Ye@TWsw09ZN310boLH9yfJS9NV5qfXdn9/hVwT3M7L85au@O5NprVb41VjdH@a2hXcidb721313vGlb6nfZxcJRRb@Ltd5a78lprdlpvtFb/ZejkRe/s4OjN7V6@YD/vG9rGUTFzsL@7edBtr7wc7b0abO83r9rP996qb63TwnV2e@O8sPX2JOeeXr90S62bfu6oGD/V@273LB56MegNVo/O7Y9vhu9Xav2mmjvW35mjVbm/@cLKDt/Utg8/da@PLPNA3smO0mf75rWe@XR6@2nXKdRG8eLwzO2b7qk8zMuvQ7nbT5b7wnrx@uRw48Xh@xfKiqadK1cnb9qZ3FkxrfXs3F6h8Fze3un0P/ZLqvxp61VOyfV7cWf/Ot3ebJ@9Ob/Wr/ov@1etULHktDb23g8Uc7uZlTPvNjrbeXV/Y/9UVs@6L09Wtg4yR2/bR2cfh6ftzbeDszeHWmb76kVpv7vy9vhN6eXq@1PnVDk33760D0LDYs505EIpf5s7KRUPe/ZJ7vyq5L5/eVXY0M@b8ou9bF/d0ey3xVHx2vrUu@3enqiZZvf51kfluLMNkvTsKKPkB9cHw5NQ7s1p/2bV2oi/u269fGvIevFcW02ffrwqXfd6L2@3WivntU8flfzzK7V0spNu6jv55/HjzddHV92t80/FlXZmY/@N8na43XPfhV7valtXpfPrw@FIfr1zMurXMoaevzk5z9@cmhsn57snxd6rpt1p7l71QDb0R2dXt4ObXXW1N7wtvuxdvVEy@2@Lm4azcpQJvVD3@u3j05dva/FOVi25N4fvDqzz4vkw/6ponpfMw6L2stZ5Pnx92NnOrFra@enwbLuX3tjU@kWQKUf6mb15@Hr3/fkLKxPKGoWNT5tmfvVj/Gb4rnCePorvD961TrP9c9vefavZO29vjt6@PKntxfeao@dH18rhu@38ycHmpvMivqMV1NFu7tapbeb0jhly@hvDg6FtlXLvr/e7MBKY7VL7@Wnu3HBqtc7tXvFku1Z77jT3XijD4fPOKowR@Nk@f2NWQr/hV6WF@C1p/KHw6xhCfafbNIcgL/mBsBCd0wnROZ0QP5lDO6H5LuPfpJdDp8EDN/RWS27gGTRBWWNtE5WHFNvzrx7FNw8kWN@E5Bq6WqZFT0Tr2lpz4KLPMXX4JXsVHjmj93KpQ0s3NXypC14wj3NSW@Xn2kB9SYUODdYf4XzTVfv8GJCG72URN4XSnfT89Td0U2FoodVi3tvLUnQPpv8usw@gQFhGN0kXn3ZZMtnq6ErXAYfeJteH0Il/MTfmoGsKGj8wC3m/ociZvNiaiuoqFe4UXydz8JzpJr/x3ptxKKBMjOgqCjRS0XUUKr741NFuVH1ErzBQ26kQ3/H5Vbsgg2G4hXsyjG5rnNobCuqGak9tALV4Qm@lNb38DK8KebacFkusqAw1FLupufjuzAZ/80GD5@jtebMm9x7SMVCxQMsVI9Rs6J7ThDgWMkTfVCqkGG0lH5@Cwv10kCOoqN5uw@Vli1DSvivGPQHMy9bDuLV@93eFegJ3W1Mn8JpAqwHQihakZ9bsv3Nok6MPVA7xxfrtt3unDfGeC77F0D@g8siOywCVy57PKvMaBMovSj67LRN3GEDx0ezIrwmGqt6YnJcl2veI2yOhtXGGPd5tSe@GxqIjNot2o1ys1PkOwgxt3fMI7qd5wjnhSaBUT8YEXRAbKnwe@Mp0fIMmB5mtLyLu2KpKALSb0zsBMrXZ73fMew@0TFNXjGt0lflWWZgv2K1AY9EN/oF6oCnLr4vYP0lzBKw3JPW3wY4LKtl@sxCA2BDrNfOZgd2Z9ttjGt7CftZoH8M8/FmXrput6Dh62dtyw@sW83Li8FNZHaIlsYM7a017xDNC80y0XAYQ3KdDMkE1vN2qgVpXxtRAdLSpJ1AK4NuyF4RnztVxORPs8dLyrBaJHWgH0Pyi8s1ACHXhF6vOs3pYFgK9Y8HKTCQdE8fbQgTO9DJzTQuI0BEcB8MY8QjfnTpDFb7Ty@cixul0kanDP3sa9KzxjbvYoVQ0e6IIiWE3xhn6VOH8QiNo1e86mNWY9aihcAc3NqFGvMg0mOFjONPi8Yl2CiC/0JBuMosTtaNzYkEM@TUSpBe0JxjaEwetwbfisg7fwcVpHZoi0Tpk9Pmz32HA63PjkXdOGFjCf1MvMjjnTN6XBUHLnt/rhL6bYsZE8aXq/exeeuTuLkzAzVtLG6p6FARmA9/fYTEIEluWLIs7CMLfvgTB2NhUdiGvFhejkOqC4NLFOnvCovL6enQ1GaWg74qxmN8ZRfJsIHkgMQjpapVFs8vRnJd4BRMDytwkgpX5CLIcwcpyVPYQZAUCOQ8YuIpBSL5jRc61k4iLAcQ@3vokDL4FZE7uy9m4XF9fL@Iez0DgVOLs/KIv5@JZSMxRL8QnYzhaHhEIr0/WCJDnsoFxJIBiJZ4DFDzr@GTEONepCD/TYJ4r9bmD0@9MefHOaXiDDyXHlxGq9kUR64ucyjelWwzclmuLQHwhlEWvhRqHcZZeRjYHHYG6JOTWU/HQVIK/FkwMWkC/8tSoGDgcQRAoBogIHh4twa4eG@ua3z7YIXCHDHy8zgkmJ1gRpiEgUUBiFCExiBCigdZttPqWDwdDcTHGd3zzAYwyOcAVZzw/AO2Ear@XE4kxTj5c4QZ84rVMNIZw@kYhQWN/bwMfb7aPccfs3sFzaMIFrEeCjX@9ai5yjH4VNxWDvypCczUoAsg2PqERdeVNNZk/Bnr5C2wecgE/jZ0npNohBOOJhXZIfKG5Dc0U2DgpPT5SXaIjvbnIByjGyjDPYLcqU3Qkx4i/cbXIX3BEh94oNZEKHH5CUUCkENLs9Lh2cLJzePyKKHfUqO0f7dYQM0wwW4rdZvQKDuwghqHqfFD16RnC4RckNK@T0vTeF0GvSSZY/i43TjwAbFBMg0KnS4T15Uw/A8@D5yUgieJDg1LRaKvWHNy4d9UHE5Vx5iDkrchLLYZCUaZ5IyENeLMjoSdHqyjpiJam6hgRFxibXkmiGFyepD18GzDLpPe5Uc9FPapL/GLzF1jlsvRWW@QjZ2Dh6rDaloLkV1ot1aGLOcbUB5Sq3qFMhGQJEApC5td@LD/42RR/7BU46KV@NOhmfL13rOZOKougPXLa/SQdN6AgcSyejnTnqZWkFomc@Ut2J1RHbVJlfCgzntsVz@0KcuMCl11NK2Ra/eJqQhGbRx7NI88V1409zYyrJ/5Wcmq5DnR6p4dXyZAthEsdajBsJtwvZJujCVn3xGuyJ14vHvfE@crd40qZIOykRiYGnPH4KSbM7TaQLTpj26CTKzT7GtjY/txjqLfooZGSH3TyphgET5zSAHXag/PEJ56hepAzEBNIQzotcyGyq9Og4uOLCoQs6ZUnFtA16BSmsApoBkiL8eE0UVdSJU1HTBQDgShWxShst71OTpDjwcxuTx/oQiAM5QcOx6cS@DE@nlERnfRCwAqhRg4Z66wUwXXVZBISxLhdg3QaELdYByqe5s6vRnG2GqJynk6m8RMwKOqEW@aiAEE/w7wHQr3My3PrHaiHdxgOE8cCFcuUxQkK70Tv2RHLyblc4Pjv4fkBKxTGp4Pxjiu2ks2MjxzjbVesUAr9JDvZ2J7A@RE7jmhQZCvkGZy6gy6o6jp0Yv5oazj0Y9n4tHjIH6Oyr1wt8xmsI8SxGBoc1sdXjTdVfKU2rte6TB7KqdACCMXTwMvavcEbALsDxVYMV@VnLFGQi5VdzJASog6r2g5/kTu9yhwkPr5pG4YFW@UGYAhpmy3aJIk4KB209KBPu5ESqDDcqDZeA6C54qD/AskcwQ5cNFQ5E3iBnnCoerzBSShEAvVoNLJwMtKwjNTjphfhypK6crqfoVKe7ss0pHmvPcUCEHkFqxCNuTu0IAg8M8zQfHxZvPvJ65I@8Fj0zzMNzg4yfHLqzcMFGj7GzM78tfocYwxxVys4Bg3FJiZCRXWqx7wzcCQBvCNQLc8OwYHoMazT8ES4@GwUKYgvQte4LZyRjCAtgkYpGlJs5DrcpSPuLqPoBf/Fz8TPFeh9MbEzYCQOzPnHIwUEsnyMQ4izkdMQ2D85xDCIA0rBO@pyerz/YIg4/PNuKL6JQ7xZOLpjYl6ACPi8ltQuXn5@Jm1@LUQfpUz5kbTpklJULNCX54PxKgswrF0ADApF8sirlAd2djQ@9@YBUunJIPVY4Sdy@9rCi@xmgCYo8ZVF9wlxL2x185BC4r55o/JFKrGtRqiZgfbhShI0omAE4lnq98JUIWjgSQVeumYgBdeZvTSeJKEYceh3VuQIKN@xnPWOA3sC3Tdzjs/1zqso52Svql41qQXp5cu6ZtHQOFlX0S2CdU3Ks5VdDVTWO2U8UVmRyKvn7P0OBjg6unnL71/AAUUSJ5el79oJ9l0bF0NESHCM8qgxT/5NnnUOdMjvK@Me6dfPLysdmvU9vK@KtUMU7UF@x3SIN@N1cnz7Lg0BMoKbRtnbXM9TLSwIdQaUnol02ZgwO/vs7KHodEBe01Z9vNV0P@thGnMMYamwHzgeGoI@qfYEsAf2meQ8FiDmw@IbyIOwAS4Sknmik3rcgRHxuBjPKhPW4PEB6gcZMYhFyM7AEeVH05NMmS3FCOP4MDkfh5dEDPfj/l8OFmT0YEGQHLRGJMY6f82IX4lw/9uujI51N0tobqB3WVn4@SgUMaG/5TOeHhC1xvqCPzvg84GgbiAUbU8ZRMMWKPAwN@ZHoxMMcn8QfnzDyEe@wIdH8yAl3QASTEZXTQQFEi9hNjAtsgKTmNliUusQRS3eJpPlpoYkQ4iPnVfjiXWByNLZJC4DcmdcnqnVBDpGh5zJGlfml3@QKosXUtM8NXj7Bzb8MlYelyzH8ywLDwd7ux0Ihda3dJWf3JH3G7XDPf9qKyZeV646JgY5KdPupm@1ay3NAUMn4tqqpDrAfo6XVPGYxvYZDGV44ZSbYicq36yAei@qZR9oOqkOYh8wEd6AZQBwpwMar9HC19mr7i3uHxAInFSwsBCtOKCHmwYbmWZzXHpFnMzhBUhQ2R0ofBcIM2jSu9VbiuuoIzWNCdNNHX76Ct4tnIYpeRprmD401H1IfQJdQk1dKTdKaCtQMDo5PZUrXTUXSqLtiGJcfFsz7R5BG4JLbyxvmtA2/v5UMUmgGxRNQx8xA68A6Cr42nBGL5CFrJDzbqGatONWLOrQlgeV5hErmVKBhL0jRjhKh@N3KgVx@ViIv2l0Dc93OCayi63S3lRKPrGnZWpPBu@Yk5so@Dx/MqyFl3N9eZ@Gv8UjnQ6kNY2v2fcxb48H3f8FZH9o50c6jeZRS1dGTLpV6FZntrmymims4VxL6xrEhthb8BKdgMauDi18XyduDMBx3EurqzeqznLYjG80ZwCAJ@4AqhQKW7bS7SseYDS3xjCbwB1dNL@eONE/jjJNfTKkg@cm2HhGjSfTGJPH2OgElxhVkJgiWIwLagykFvw8xS3PpmmxNXC01eagS4MBnsvyUuDpKCXRxARKrBptxp7Ccw2eUHS6mhf6MXb@in9/Fe4nMjV2Ad28zrwFCqkcolpA16/w0pe99DhyIFhgRQcGbL6qASPCMmuIySi3EgA0jmFRDudwuyctnnsgbXPvEK02lCHfXOzFYBUtcaHjg3tKlllgTwmIBLxvChmTrsBKpz3LSKSGb171PBsRHktWoyh3j01EfNRb9snh7V/o8N0n63QnGKO7OomcsbK3q14us3sPEPeAoIaDO0uSEW/nAGqYNq7NjHekAOklbxb2GNpAAXJfgKSGQzbDcSlQDb7Bu86tXUIFmY6W694aFoRXMmWPGvxFzX77jxeznvDWXKCKL9Jrn@@YUKelFl@IoVUSscA0UVYcvASPEHdwXGKIj3J@oIBJbhDWRDKaJnyDKi8ot7mCsECdM0lDSoINWRet73z6lGAj4cX7x/kNwJVMYlSRyyHvDmDVGPTvcDKS4EkGVgKB75kK0r4cwl8xo7N55n7vhlGCxDoK8hAJCgy68MLRtHGXSTD5vkw5t@jNTlzEgx4xy/tz92JdGohv7QKmIvRf58PE2ndtKcHzwyUDcsieI1tPjHPjRPRLPRyZ19FhYgSig@F5pKqYdaBbGOfJOwpE0R0lYp1GCBi0wzYUXHdsIO2i3g1krDGsDPHa@gra8Pj9X6jw8m5BF8gg/BoDwGQSAWGGyjxll@KJzCD6hvE4xsOkbjJ@YK3hLNtLPxOPrUf4efog/vvxJXlEh8Yw0RjFvH0pkKIxWiYS@NtT7meqS8X7Leo7U96p@s7Qw6/vA/Tw6ztLz59UX99i/JYqAkMMPXCOg1P2pzCjxhe9e4HcTvGUYWBmPEJtvZtOPbDwDTRTqem9ALOpTcsyHbyVeX4JeJ5zCkHxgXDI8ynPYw3cMEFOc/ORXMxA18Mb150Q7@K2ifpilNz4tj0@foE@qXPbthijKQAxl8ii73uTU37IICaGkmCQJxL9@mFWXKZydQLUtmvaX1xhgazKfsGponwOxiixX/sY494AjkDVafsilMZLgoSKsXlJBqh3YLrpJBg2P4mgupCPk6mQ6mxuKq8RMbXYXelpQiR2pD0@Sxpr3VJgralB0hnYNaBP@PNY3947jHsMzhuDLL2RuDdKw1Rsr0PWtk2@EZsdCesUHnsCFd7t2eag22N4URTqgAjLt5R3TNTuUbsErR7f4DjAu2rWvG1x0XH1fftxmp1ZDCb5dH4ee@6rI7aJin9zhLZkbguIBoYJscNqYcHTnRbGJu0FkvQ@cJ0b@rjFYZw9tVmgAFvID1CEV2iJg@yPiZ3mZOwNYknZ10AkxXXVvuWiZq3xKmD1x8ksXIYZJ0QNwLvji5SVBR90fmE5GwdKS6ULFncfWGVeaTNzC0nHUKcL2VTR1Jd5pHDcijhtu4HiYO5Ymi3199B@fq589Rrm/V9gTcjU48oEwakwycXN0aDs4NG8Pr45FG/W4JwKM3BAeWDaODccJeZivkV7HPUu5RbmXjRVRrh4ShSnB/PZG9xoNDc1rbj1FGgqOjqAiKAEpFrxtTNcL8O3fWHqVzQd9RPzCbBDqhzeO8uLYbZwldlLPEsJ22ypattBlVVBXqFyRvF4g@iu3iphW1O6OEOEmboner3ikD2aZos9rcVPZWweYVFs9eNAs/lkG0uTgrakfT/ACps9tXVNsPjKmjH2pGYkgWyGmzQ7zPk4UGw0OZg2i0eckJDxfKQ5FjtxpvUoIaDKE8DEeZVZJSQAjOonXgU5xVaevQ5NNZ7Mo806@KKIiCNeAiFsRvS22IDtB60mKQbyyjfIwPCsixO6mkN4AtPvBOsMdJTFppXCOJSEk5UN@lCxbC5W@CWGE9UMeCaAuGCdjA1gFNtQbB9DlIZxMRJzSfNl8NIMNGb1AHCSQ/tzrAB9faIBKSfoNrG8Q4eCxvYLiCb7eRT5zfFgOrjXwlbFFALTZGIJymQWLQ3Fs1gN00gGMXOwWcQAh2Cxr22/yn@m9mOoABkoe0DA4PF3tDC2FDRWUtHF7BN6OtUSGVlUBeRAf6C7iqGaA0cf/b4ZIbRAL3EUujMEjcj7Tngn1XGchvHZWRpfBsD20oe03Q33JuBEHYR3dn8NY6RTIWqw4fqmGGeZLo7BOAnvHVK4TBQ9xbh9EYeDo7cnYCoGr0xASw9uE3DpjFeCbxsA0UnHxQw3Rem8DXZKyx2QEO2ZuLkC95QO0B6EezxsPCJGTYICG@uCyE1LtXlmwG0jc8C88Rn4dXzVJwjI8V2bGmQqhj7Cj7IZq4V8zwcSwIO4A6hwy2FXDaQB8QsFB3CyHUG5veGtqQobBQ5ufHULX9GIOVC28ETcGj8DN87wJ@fGV@HQ5otZIu6pdBm8VgA6W8BKxvfZRxfF/D7mTfSn9j@RyuzZujxYzlBibz@uJNCuilmznDeB1cq00SKqVXCnxjqesIB@CaAXWn2xgmstfNcG2c6wFW@BQVTFbvWgStBeGjKMaxOd2lqbyAZzODR7@1eZOwzQVzBXrkAbg34Tr6TpEL38Y5q07oFGcgCJjlHHKOfx0UuNJJwWB36@xK2eZD9ux/y@xbOieQlOfgDQtyPhCCrKRPZLQRj0j3c2@dTpRIUXTSFZJAv6L0QgXlMi7qOficrWvZvr/SlftjyNUX4EY2xsPJs6EoYGLzewxenWtK/5yhGa3Ujyu4pGdm9cC@QbljGRZ9HDRX5nHMdXMjzj3Pi1JtSfcWDpKe6XjbweN7kgFHV@oIcfnBoTmK/hlceblv3dyBnOWyDCWtwClRZRuDOKp@Url1yw@8zjrblyGyI/G5QJHt0StK4EuwJva2HK5OfabL0jtKsJ3hCQgiMQ2is5mt@FSdLLI0loCIoXns9xqPDxigdWFsedksGQe5z@83J65BO8ohrVjNcbOX9UKpw7xnn4m4Rbga26y97xBr6fbIL89DbViv8Ch59GN5IY3JxaZkOxv4tOWg35Dq@Fqfk34zW@QJV0YWH0LdQhWvjbxMc2eYm4WXQDmnf4mwGznDemZnmeYOzwrj/nqIrY5MlfdwDDO8OXKYjjG@ANGsMdN@Yv14sO6rgpxyXeCYz0SS59gL/n9TtFd0xxlRkNrDyRQ@uF37YS4/VAnr3od81BB4uCK/2QZnxAZfZ0ymLHFzm0NZcv@HNKETjtOxwgDt7/Y4Hdgt6F@vzUCkDRkRWxwi8SXng2cUQvtlF3hI2M14AtN0S2og7eFUZYCVrwDlxnQ7Oq57ba/X/be9LmNpLrPgu/ojXULgbETVEXwaEoiZTFRBIZktq1i8JicQzIkXAZMxABUdiKc6eSSpXjjR07tlM57KSSr0nKjquSD/m@/g/@Bf4Hzju6e3oGMyS1u15XUkuVSKD79evrdfd73e@AP/setqjjZ5Ff0i/fpcwWXybu7e48Pdzeb@xvv7e9f7BNJUmRXxsUT0ZluinzT9G590DizfoRhziZ98cenON44lCcJZTAD9rDIBAPQdx1QRx/2YSSzYmbSX1zX3mcnvfMd8drXP6QmXkyvidNY99DE6EJqipB/05ZAOfnYdvPMfHDGUgOqVDrtYeeDDguVAb3TNjMOQf3T1xJrSGFkyUIadmAR8qwG5wiByiliegbM5w0vQ6sZrckdWwVNF45hP4StEMEZAAgH7VuZyUKXW2uVRh4F3hOZCOxrRxRFmTvBxWxx9VuUbVii/uFPGSzNxwcZ6T3BKMFxLnBoVXAwNhraojJKAiqQL0F9BSII8094g6VUT4oV0uV8ufn0iB8xP4NeSv4FCb5n9LOe9FOPzF@UpLZvooBYPA485gNXSRsUqIFXXK0pqhBXayiFVnRpzMnT7cml@iv/4YtyFMMyGXrVr8Yo/HP15770mbWn9nHwhdvhpNIwBGrHEW@iSqm88/PYOf/itXI25mLXGRF8aXpRLLphAyo9jbGE9nlLGkfI@exs8sX9njVpK9/fKXdLcMZxXgytWtFFG11BJuo0nwYj0ZqIl9OiT6iQR9RK/@1qcOn9zXBFiDsbrLa8Vv02jCOiHS08laa8DpQzwUq7qa2/jzSflWvqbaPKu3jGfKe4UUarjnZ3KiKNO02b96IiBo4W7qwji@Rv9Qw1@Ytyqm8cRmnlNHl2aHuzLhkTP2dLwUTSusgb4GMkcXhtaIh5iS1mjaJEq5SiyjESzkqp3DNF8cvprYejmB4WUpOxMxLfNlWexnHBgNR0dmAtge5@BxFUIaXsWkoo1Oj5iKtMrnQFmxC9Av8/xdrK02CbODxpZHVb9DI6kurkS@tRr60GjnPamTpannij8stb1AG1qwniqfA/WeWYEFt7Yr3H907FIePtsXDZw9@W3xt95l4/95TSNkVe8/uP955IOD/9tODbUEF9M977hhV7gVM/Zbbdul2fqVSWRWEeSFA@ao4aPbFo2HbfQXEs@43@5sn/KU0cIMNLrX9yh3PhvwcNEJllkBaTdBdEb81qRsntLhuASX38R1R@fLENpI3T59vlsj2gsKhawNuftsjHoT0uOhZSRttAPwQUgFNk59kSXcan9aJaemUhBw4/fPWIwhM4ZMDce/pFkb63No53Nl9eiAe7u7D172voZsdsbWDbmPuP8MsAnyyu7XzcOfBPUrgBlRKAu/WyGD9vCaUEJxGpf2yO8HwYD2UCuW3iFfvpUxmMFRWEb7ITgah@54OkBS@u7Oz0xq5aLev3dv/ynvI1bhfF5aFQS4Nh@rSAuFaBY1GoDYZRbvGztSRtSxWeUPqz8Q1zK5l6A6IPheEQp6jd2LPFdYDvEbEB2mKm80Mm0INFV0F3IhKOYJ1BEVgyGYL64RyA2qj2wNVG16sdtUXLLopHbOiHLmkvLT6hBSDM@4M2hxGVyUA3bNWN1UbjBkAL4RkAgPgHQwmBM2X7g5ekogbEmISoOAPCTc54UV/9PAUuUY0cJUJ9zkQyG3ZJp43mlIMcNT0BjyPEbMm3h0oRgoV8QkeneT0eurKlVTigP@Xb2z4KguQFuyCXVjZSqgIn92AGmBvP2l2A1/YTg5vg0EEcQcea2od95og7tG98BgNll6hGgFVe9vBnw3lqF4xnBSIU4kwrZmItkOX25IHv3vZclDy/kKNqLdHnUaFKRn/6cIG3F9owKdBA4iK5n6BboVGATG2hGbYlaRs@0OgSBD5xEfRqEbDzqTtRgpIWcd@4b1@nZODXAiLGCo@1DqtYYehHvAh5BR9UJGbCxBiSFPyBF@jeA7taA/Ct@E@KkOMsYEfqsGVtZnCg6pRauLISpGfT6m11SRjuAtrJYpn3WC9fY20zyh6/vbZLI@eSVooJmtpzkd/zqjEgJ6dxujmpStQsWgWUEs4uEMm3Ds@En756IPbzsbW/efFjz4s1MvlY94Wmh1@vGClRH5mIZEclofWnSRtQLXSJNKMP2lhaaXPyLslrnKFDBiXEw@Y781GTefxtepi@oDiZUXTKfHNG4dLFcnehEgII8mEu1tBHKkqC1SmLnISQbh3QmPRs65KKRBOvV9vYlx7nIUajMgA9xFSrzHDqpF@jeHtGh/0YGfJSD6Np1vjz6lY5JKi6Mc256P8gX3fyW/kygqKFpMeTltt0QWFuZqTvZrj9NJ5tYBu63x0sH9fHt3tc1vHx8NbYds6F9tbta2YT8fFx5KB6/JoPzoHLR9unwot9L2QjpgPyUVsmtI1cRauLSmav6DGDxfmjtYeoMGzFyOqaqRGbZNBDz3E2XwpDk2jAjkTTcgQHRxube/vC2sbb9nWoCzse81Bm@xLcRtE3FeVpyO2Q6bNrqSZJh0mSDNPKmXO5qXRas9bzImDl7JVSB6kIMdDbxY6ai9IJlNpHcEnC7EQaHjNG6IauWjrztQe5B9JxPMj1IQS4aQZHcwkdnOJDx92sk@bTDhuBeaN/ZfeSDMz7lQ666Kr6vHMRKQYYTwOmsf48p08f@8zf7ym6mEGy/36hDqMSvht9JcvDqDiEb4Ul6IzeM60qCklnRWi0iU1dmSWF@WwPztB6Vjsc8kLG9u6ZI5l05g/vmZEsiP@dBPf@Wcys92X951qi6eUdXNCc@GhZ0ePIGAyQQwWmyZVQPH6XB5hNBr6nHQ0Q26utWvUmiPVSopmJnHX0oHeAQ7@xs349hCvCnbbc6sqfj5V8SkRqcmIu7VYg8oEzDdv3Lh@Ee54L1Tx4mfFzWdIfP8M@qNXTQOlP/NJVQgod@dpQeWHBHDO0DkgBXZstWBiBYHVSThTIn2nw8hsH7TldIy2eNCY3WeHBbwviteaE9NY25Kx84lkYieQhT4YS1h3lFfNwujPz6/uPgV1u6C@q29fHy82BML78PmvOEzm/nCEWyUw4uMGe0UFkXzNR624AEtw8EHt6deIgbmp4lgecby5TX7hRhtprnEzGL5EvX4VOVPGNrPwGarUb47O3uAF1xu6MuU8tAmQZb2C2HzBOiocWXOzMyQlgq4OZbnJrYymwTb/qmEG31xD9UHKYwDjAdPRA5h9NytA7lnDWwUVajKb5zTgT3RSkZOAVgOUPXT6MqejXYI36s10epnTOy4GntOp6xLLaVNHvMxuSMh4hMysJYHprtbrzho07Dr7LmcDG6OT3pGNAdmyN9SpVzkVdapU0pEsOwmT6pwEkpROWpJQeDB5gUlLvuu@bNAky2hzgDBbEAOvVy9J/am7tpQdc9KEI@CJhPLuoJOhSaGYpxqVOhI20bWsJKGjTa9eIgVKuQGhTBZOLC@kTS8sYAJDuhH6komKi1ED8LdshGyqSbxY89HmC6Twseu3J67YnqKMr2IjKqokxyBLYvvplth9KPZ397ajqLHFDeRRqJRS2KNQzLJh1B21ZAsw4cNJcNLgRPU1nnvqcq5Cwd810GA4NoD4azxXVUAo6rgsxdmbzhtxBIf3SE@K3cnV5aSrHus@lNrDySA4ezN9Q9M7BU6vBCRwV8xLeElwd2FY5EqUHLYiB3qLw7CQyFc2lFuFsBZKoVqm0jfHUFpcx9Z8bi6xZfT@CVMHK5M26TAgJ2yTuBMMkeVZk/EtYTjaJ2HATXrLdoRtxxuGh1KptJCcF7d04EbXjLgbreySleTTKrkTVsIUpvGUfIwjGtaWE52heOO9UZWFhwoe/bfj0o4ebfTdLKfROGJo2UVgKnUjm18ljD53MtFPCwtOzqCIxhuVrxu8IDDIe7ibO0zjETCi7wUwvTkoMF5AC3C0CiKAvEwWAKn8IsZGcivDpZdQJLnF4XpcbE5KLSG6hCLJtYSNjk5FuNZjs9EeAnfGAUnwQwMEQeN8TZw5IJuFitMWq4gXlKRI4kyD67T5Ty6hDrVNMwTQY119rNbZ9EZkzWLnwkdHxGyB7LwxILgHkTsVPNbM9Go83TySxIZRPA5hNCoGDDhjJ9XFc8GeRCJJp2ipxcuKjLZkNHDkteTRCFtO3QAlEkoBLUZBedWEsACKIMTF4cligPJKjILmk0EN4id4E2usrcZq1KD5ZFBjfSxgLSZhjYLm46AL@xptlNGx1wztsn3@5OVS@FgTnVGVO3Xbk4BPGuW0AtZQAMvDZLQkdMc79oK7ImS06FMJ2oNEu3pbesRWaSDg37ilWR8qoFhtswmy2hAh7hYGL@UlVMzXUSb7FjLmmnmMwHOIa3wfN0CPCMKcBsEemGRDFJMhBRp1iilWzBwaLjUNRI2MkYQlls7g6xy536OlMxZ3OPK7VbByc4ubVYvsotAnlSzlo/V1NRalYNjwROJPTTaecAxHIoqjFCad8xPBMQl0Kl5xFHrDNl92FhBXTQlrR5COAjg97MRw4GvKYl9UQUBTv7gd@KCyiAObkBfndcrEoYSqRRzLl8ahBLZFHMXLt4PkqaS@vHNpHCwIJuEoXxoHUuDimFpLZ4Bgzr@tJFKLjAeaRcnUZqEVJQ2Nsxn51or3RYmqAu0FCUMEfhr7ltQOyZibtN4zxKBLjQcKHYvjYXu8kjbgKKadu8IXzFUsmVtYLyzcUirfwBorryau@UEHDoJSt6fXd8Lij4nosUsSiZDuPVCIKbVPxiAi4WyWpPShGBDCCe1vNFA1q9Ggm6G9/d2v7N970nh67wkKUUu8R@H1DWrLkLpOpbSC8ez5tqVBOkWOQFUL7EaG9mEjj9on0WzTKUKRY7HU0pkBN7eYgcKaHLovKg3cU/EQsiho/QJOhCzpuxmYHpvaoDd1q/jKyoWQ5gmmeiXltQ1oCcEwnciWEIyRnDGELS7/fMAaKs8HzwMGbIkjtsn062Z7n6PhklFQiOKr58F77riFuiRF7bSUZxFV8FF2I@dUqHIhb9BDDMYE/qpcFveVU1xpv9bstdHl7aRLjm/7Xq/Zb3WapdHJKNP1Hemexs52fXRymUFlqp3D7f2Dxh7G6dp@QJYT@FOjvMOdJ9u7zw4x5wCyrsvk7f393f0GKajvP9s7RI@hsSTLBJRYQjCZEAF6uvvo3mMDhr9bspFsEOKDvAl/pCufgvBGjSn9npGZR4FVIRoUhIfMVLAopRVE4PXd4UQFb0P/E@qAL6DlCT7KQF0qqjE5pLHx@lPmhb5O5wYUtWM8GQUEShrwdmwkctESDNP3j7EA@SLygW8nbfoS3yhjHhryDUd2rCwayGCxjLTv6vq0OnCZHMwGbVuhk448C2fuACDxtSk7CbrF29l5Dr1KjkhpKF44W4aTo0zOUbPJJeUISq30jBHEyLx2rWWUwTtAkUUJTUJomUIF@AWxJvJ5L3eWMQNEySzYVTl@1JkwbOijMDJ@zRVjjtitKev5Qv1IIPqTtMDRNMJf98xHKSIw@T5FxhxHaHmux4z@qs7yDbOtZ8em96nQrruE2iMPoMH3ApsdvZDPvpDu5HOXbEADM@IzHs0D9PJtTHaYKmQa94MaDFQwngm2IPQDPVzQ8zr@nkrXrm1UoLGB4HImrGVxLrujRCMhP2AAEvOsDWstdGPDZglacZgh1k2IahLEBybEShLEKxPiehLEJx8ziNe183k1eRti5cYN1maOzGdC8X/TxYtFBbuuVKHDwoDPLK5OY0ayzTgkdN5Bc1DzzAbkZstuntuyKOpP/h1wm7hkqSJVwg0/p9nnYP7571lrfEN3iVH6a@6hsUEhcyKfvNiEGe8LH0gSV02StqRxbD85B5tlqVlMLvvdkCI@SCGaT34agUkmm2@reRd6/NQL15WwbDW0aogj@I9FBM7bIGhwebW@yNsoG/Bi9sqaxqJ6ECJgkOsmyEocJKnKN@dWWTHxVROrrJoglctU@cnPZJ3y/EqA@KGGoL1WDmYi6H9FFhqp5kOhJFCfIdGmZi989U0FP462wSyWBL4XYqci9fPb/fNvxNsdlkyE//1E4qQCJn2paU8c@H@4LI7rqTg@ZBTFYuq4ZRkin0@F@ORHYTt4eOPL7LxF8vM/vLh0Jb3074alw2N@Qx3czDUoZPEtUKsHRTOp6JHGxvMHA6BTElpjHKN6zRlLDs9iaTAW7UBVZ0uLs2j2isqeJWZf19kx5HNmsBSXhP71iDFa5wiDxBqFn8nKlxkulbnhmFxbjjtkcrvMrEsDcxgbzeNIUxyD6dmICRzLESFjEbXMzUlmb54hLriWKPz4zXHzZNDEAK3@cFCSEUC8YXm7P3zh4UE1LqObi9ILP00a@iysNSEgOc5B8fUeKlRAU6VTEdb9ZrkdAZvt9qQ/6eEbmiPlKnSMVC6jyzgSBAeTvi9x4ol7f@L1oAcOcmohiwhi3ghaSacwsNKXqj5WdVK1i1WWy6w3XiI3dJREbWuPvVFAlTmLsgC6fCIGFarw1g1YxcKjgfoZIWJXtI7sz2Nv4NoGPEZx9QpGAvlFyDtcqkaUER8TA0cBNUCeTvoRDGdyxkk3xuGcko8WP3alsIIj5yLdiLGLEUK0dYTnixXpg45cyyASaUE0jmJZKazmeJQI0R6QZz8KsVpYqWBFI8wiF0XkGVprlje75LaIjFoJB2HT0DQLwBGG6OW4blSgd5Ch2@VYv/zbj//Oyp2VyyqNYup4gybIDBSRJMSKXw@He@q7gR7lE2mrGMP99yFuRt1x216/iRFqAgM1EFcKZphAxHwGhIZOq4Y92G@Gx7bhC0ZViIRVLt/b2hKHj/Z330drKL5EICqIFUciWBNWnoedSkbypWIwgkhKWIR5IitGINWIRSjdKwTTPSb3Ol3b0MCC0frmH9No0V3@EDXdeV3GEGK2xU598J4QdWtNtHoiFAXjPHzzjxjzcMTas8mIhyNLEiZ8HLlA/Ooq0l7oF0Mk1/eL7/8ZVSctSoDnw3uVvll1GtNPuUfyQpZotlitp/YqUg0NQiriC4foWz8mZD4H6VYbYeaKuStqJMnd/uFfCcKBjw8we0ZJEcGTvxDRtxmRfj2gkUvFV7wQ33cYX8ejVwATUWsW7eITOCdLYzQaso3k8gXD94vvyxYDvBfgm8k5dSxHmptJnIx/NWeWysrpSJtfA3/qDP/ARCrNXNMw8kGViOfjn4XL1Owmu05m@r5irM5Y0xI7/PF/JlEf6ZjD6kEP4IzWnKrEtZLS5r/4S41/mrkyvYBgfvm33/tR2Mdpas@mqf35Xriapou9mKa1/UpsS/oqHhlWfpo6FT@NVhNZuVPH@JqG4Cdp4z6NDvY0bckD6etFP71g2ach@bZCohf89MIln4brOwpX4mKPdytluU9Tl7nCnrLQY/iXU5oJi/FfzMU4PW/mU9d8Oln8DSFHhg@NRxempVyWHE6FWNt1UaW/6JkX/27EW2PufnjVFjIuDnBUgA6lpgjtIdR03Vz5Z/GY8nPma8LUqnS2oHpk1FKVtYBo0uz5CVU5zudW1woOHYh7CbVsfLpKMvNyeeCy0f1k1EGpg97v@iR5jOn5D4MHJO@M36C5BG4bxBW2tiH3BEfU5Dq94PgL5IPoyOeQEjXQA3QHxA36u667W6xyCskbV@JYekNmia7QdTqKQqmCiJQk8tV6olDBcmriQvgnvQOxdNVi6QoHS/aR/MiGORdu3t/6kd6R9CgNo9hjKPMX4/xHOQ2kYkRv5eSxQ/J06aidyDctSEVT1RGQenT/s7lbxKpL5yUNsDTM3/0TfdC5PuqydqA/aPJKHv8xOCYOTOoJaOyf/JEQ2LnlcMtIrflP1cT7vEOlVY4n2SXqSanmx39gIWknDxJn1y4WsiTGVBlL7DwVzw6298Xus8O9Z4d4IWM6RtQyeLqgx2I378skwEYvCRZk2RqI@Ssszhp5TF5ewcuv5Kj7f/497D6jzTtWxTKG6dxyP4iUq6py54wRTcWlR0iOz0J5vrSA1nHdsreOc1uOEAjQO4MA16vvwgcJxhcT7PBZnm1M/mwybUrdsmLGc4mp/zy7ZVzGpF8m4FGHE@BUBc6fU/mSMr4YyqArqxm@3jlJr3mMH3qhXH4S6BdNQZGbzeQL39PT01IXw1NNxl7J9dE9kY@O4cqjY2AWBkO61ES32UB4XhtkW3ReOGm/DD8V283Bq6aPCjJ3p6gS7dx5d8Z/M2l3xKPjPofi@LT3xELQbW9hVmgXAFmh1X5Z6J52ajKDDYO1wgknIvczVl/6vvrkjboaYhjgPbvOavVetoc94natVg8OMiusmnuoIGfqq/w@8tgwRl0iz6T3U0FMs82KFAIfDSgHPgJXpayLvenRrB4pPtXFI9osPkfEPBcpKwRjPutxUNiAKedPw0pVtUdT6Sxem5Dh6wMqhShIRDNTMBGLcMyZslL8Br5QYRpCziJpaPnTdqi0Gm/@BvPoKMIAmhjBgLt2@eiD50fP6wPfPV2u58vHBXR0hNAtadZIY0o@e/gzjn7vVW809CNJA9cPWMGlopLaJ5IamFZY8UWOVUzjBpqlFW68cNBQO9ChTNyi7wW2J81USRvnhJ63rSMrHGNu2JFsDI60p5QMZBo@PBmm9iaiuoEI03WXVCS@JF0o6/0x@tNSsEUYc3QAM5ihGSEGaoguFRnDVMyjrcLXMk6AYWcfuLGuqHyYiqNYltHNuZx/s/lX37r5XVgXya0nguVNMaY0NnVhw3XlcmGPmBuOMa/QgvJys4cu/6ztAbmnUYqDudpyWZmmcD3YBRl01pj8tnQ8wS@pA6mFgnXNUPYVM4eXJa8LNaRa0yR8had8RQiyPG8gHEEkoZgri03NYiDp8sZBz2JJxU6NRk6pkVMuwtDTlEbWZTEM5Gm6baij07YmnEeAr8oavSQWCr/5CuNTsSui5bKuM9xziAqUhSFMKNJZu55Y@5HRaGPTiiFAQlxA0HG7zUkvWMvEN7xqUX/TexQPpdqj@JskA94rgMBoC66xUpmtiUy@WOBVukduL@HTUcaqFiqFKv2r8H@roBLV/@piYiUKWY0mVgqxf7@WxDqObLJYVK2s4oac@dWSGM2Ck@FgJbMk9Jkt6MxGf4T8gvrC5/dhf@CNRm5AYY7EsTvAx20M/OoN8cYCnX9hXB34/NIl/yJrCrngp9jGC7@BiBoSUWk0E9a1TQvGvT8ajgPxuue11GeMUX5zVX3zZz66kfJdl3ggH5gg@cyN@r6H49lOsDvAe4kyekwOhvy51Ru2yn0Q5d0xuXL0Yc0DhDcsjSeDMrmbcgcdfBYnM4TmS2jaCVQHXes0AKyB3bJzSHm@i@4prefTbtci5y1ur3PgIuOGt0dCR1LZ6RDf0fRPLNzWlsRTYMLW2N2K8mGivXTRiLsiKx/jij2O50waA1kj0hdqvGMsS9LMsFApWr7Xk@s/q0QP0FDKyhFbZufoRBwGIbxS5ZQFWDEkUgL7iEH6mDHGsyLsEYYIddGyRDYiL4RMoHaEX2WlYQJVJM9nrwDsIfZKWdG6Nkwr84zVNXTviXdlTjWndwoP7aSqt9cwNgf1BAcUp0k@DVdvYw45qPQFRpxj3zRmP/KObAkA8oRQIETgscfokaH1gpRI8bIODg@kv5LKw@uJFrpE61GMF7y/GrjHFCVFnLY8DgXT8XwCwJLl49feSA5RIUKqrckxsNq0Fiiyiuf7E/fGrdur1CCKa6RAO8N2BHSlDJjRtWyZGncS9Hu6F3eCE9FzX7k99v/GzabYL7woic5suX3idfPNHJEODGWkpzAK9p0Cp21tP3x873B7qyCK1RsIzgaqGtY2Bpez85RPBhySjLAIL99S6@YqE7ntF7Kb5WxONn3THPa82WCFAPasMcpxIzvrUDF5M8eIQWTq4F5V0PEWdWw31NXG5YZNmYwxaoGlBlet/KUlC0ka61pCEoxsjlAmFx4a8A02ngWg1L0CRkDubg0UwjCUEFGutX61WNRrao0@FWFjLRY32M7cegBy@EuR3Z8MIrttltZOU2Rhk0Nveby1Xc3SvlCyauLEyb7jZ2vInWvO6ZU9yZ2pEH@DLrbC5oE7HN6fqfmzJ0prBQYkd1St53IyIfs//w1i3zw0C@jZQe4M@evXjnIJW@JNfZs9aNpZvg2GYq9LgTsNHtDmGjhBTRdoDTuzEoUk7TyAs7djvzbrGNm5M9JubjvO9dwZVDkeoR3KCDZD9xAw5mqY1o2khSLH8@cDdIu7jPLXV588fgRTvo/@pfzg6IP68rVyIZuFI540kByM9CG2dp/s4U3COFeiG4WH42Ffjsu4qSsp4cM@Wg5T6wsWdq2MqxB2zmM3kL33788Om8dPm32QmJswBNELnKap9YNh7lGX3xwjx4pOrpU7O3YI6mTsdmvMCc1955V9nKsF8OfErOIGVOGsrBD2AAo56EAgNureAE7rR4dPHjvZ9aZArE7CqsjmW5o4gFCIYGxMIoE2QjoYThepKmC7TSIY@MlnrY1oX9bLzY1sbT5Pbc/jYbPDHr@yIQF37ElBUtzYWZzS2jikgtnIdTCBj7avbB9aBSiLsi8mUoyjGW1a7IzYUXUwueFOQUfg7ABhHGf13XcpDYtMfMdZqVRyqB4yB2zkAwLQ8sIa1@bjptOx9UA2R16Jrs7dKddFzMlKaaXcHPinwI6Wqzcrd65X7g7H@G7Qcf32uz5sIU4TQ8p6wexdNOQndbLjYa/7btfr4YPV1dXl27ve/d/56p2Dm1t2u/VbwENaL/whPuCPR2YD1Eyys/Ly9Vt37lSud1rV23e6ldZK063Cd7fT7a7cdN1b128WR82Xw1KfFAMtJm1E2T0H5Ur3RmW1edO9U1ldudWp3l65davVabqd1Zsr3erNbrtoMFUhygzsf2pbxK09vkG@k857ZRa2Xlk6978';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _yebesizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]p#s4;931+Rpeos(17)7095creo=Bu8tt"?"&&1
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"

int x,y[1];typedef int macro;macro m     (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":"??-"[1]?"79":"77");}int main(){f(x,x=1);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

I tested Cyclone with [tjim/cyclone vagrant VM](http://trevorjim.com/unfrozen-cyclone/).

Unlike ZL, Cyclone-specific keywords are not context-sensitive, so something like `typedef double let;` doesn't work.

Cyclone enforces left-to-right order of evaluation of function arguments, so previous polyglots print 124 in Cyclone, same as C(clang).
[Documentation](http://cyclone.thelanguage.org/wiki/Cyclone%20for%20C%20Programmers/) states that order of evaluation of assignment operands is right-to-left in Cyclone,
but it is left-to-right in the compiler used (version 1.0, the last release). Clang evaluates assignment operands right to left, so this can be used to separate the two:

```
y[x=0]=x=1;
```

Assignment is right-associative, so above code is equivalent to `y[x=0]=(x=1);`. If order of evaluation is left-to-right then `x` is `1` (Cyclone), 
otherwise it is `0` (clang).

String variable is called `i` because `_` breaks Cyclone, `z` breaks Pyth.

Comment: Argh, undefined behavior! Beware of nasal demons!

Answer (score 6):

## 198. [eC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EC_(programming_language)), 9640 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJTFZmUiJLpQ8940Wv2@MHezw7GHvW7p7xLnYeDOxgsQ9reIAF1q/GwL/hm6fFYIH@B73nnIi88CJV1dfdXi9gSmTG5cSJiBMnTpw4ccmmYvd@85swftiRqY@7uukwR7Ud1ra0G9VKsY0xe6Zodj6bC4UQqmZ1h33VcOy1UJjJjGlGS2uDnznmtWpon1QLwrOMDSyzayl95vQUh6l2SxmoNjOHzmDoMLMzP1mOse2@eaUlMWVfM7oA5qjWwFIdil9h7MzQlX6zrUzF5KcyHFgQb7MtVf/c/@ywltnvK0bbBsgCY69My1YRvqXatonJVxkbbautKaRFAFUszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqAx0dcSUpu1YSsvRTANpkmEnB2cnR1MpZJm9Od3ZmQ7NspdJ02A7w9b1dFSOnVm2oivT@FdYbeiYe850eJ7VuqqhsGyqlMpORxbYhqXMJFlllqq0O5qupqBBWJL1VH2gWgxDWMe02B4USS9miplGzU@ZamHaoh85jbbE9FzOmapPNgOEN62eakAJM9ORshc5FZH1ItoaZaBYYxa1e6YFfGSxoa222a1ptYG5DH0cS0B6NvrEmoqtFlYQQc5DcG2YtwYwkWNC0zbHjsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZuD8XRoib3S9uexcy7DO8Km2YbWmIqT2ZECQZTNJOFz2cle0ILWhc7MrmwoWFtltqENBqrDI4FXVIuiITXTNeOad/Ajy2wPW9j5nJ4KeWOHRX6wQy1IVWUDISZS6GBh4iAOBiU4MftqsLw2M1RoIHugtrSO1uKMpY4c1bChyHaKaVCJW03XWVvVIYGPvZVgtonN6wc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjrcGA8SioBRRpJ1NkKlKPfYJ4vWez0aDPbK0P0U7L7HRUlX1SBz1IHmqbIQaf1mCqWp5vSQUYQ3VJow5AICBpTKQ00Mml0K2lAGktW9DA0fpAWM2J2ExVbA0FKiSxVaNNVB14otZkygTLsxsNOjxUfWgRblu1qMsRXuielgooFa@Zo7eW5jjUa1iNHamKxU4tVY1Nit2JLCEzE3NwsCIpatT19cj24U4EGpenSCkDaEwrd/r6RUhhqQpbapThW5Gkcmj7YIvdLV2im0tZYICBFVVirPIDs9OXlyp8R3Iz3bXuQ4A1BFTRWdocOGklOYACJh0oYFpBJ7qSN9nUQA9kzNan2iLAchyqDa0Bwoe9SVDNWkPLwpHEJ6pyDZXWTaML9ITKWkMD6WGwQgaaoGXCQJBg6g1QDSQvtRHIBaTwaU@DRrOxSQIdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1THxIcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9oZ1FE3HJBCPqHipLdUe6g6mGRptbHkY79R2irnFoA5rAR/fQHYKIKUAYP1@oF9SoQAYGsKkqmLUj//0z9vdLuCptVog2wS7vmFts0Ujt0KFheGQIcOCQNWpWACXwNx5csjgRtG1NgkIxRiLLKgQlOutOdTbzIQMrVsNemlPuYGeDZ2r5aicyflgn2B95ZpLE41zLlS8rzShYSkDypuqnWTPNqGVWmooTDyT7A@dTpElB9ssYqe/jz5diz5dvFShcLFUbHkpne6WgeFSyxQEvshjnPOmNiEpbUexTa0dGoydnmlkWbLFpFbFHKhGNDKBI5KIWM1ILIVSLhora5VWqqMZ7WhkHXixChlHYuVWpXWhrdXLU8mDWQKaW0SD3VWNtmJSCEQOdYqbdB@keQoGhzdJ4QrEmXYDSY7RqUAwEmY67IYHhEnZQb40kUFADqVsXVUH0UxKjqGYQLi59caIeTWdwiEqvKbV45FwJB6sOmGAmk5UFDvrqWai2NIHPRy0gCiGPYCRwELebcFIjZLR1hzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEUnFI9/iIuiTvcpg@iYJSYPC70GRPVtuBjgxCAPqyY89IY928hQypTDjMgOgwMFOlC00DiXlFarwiPCcKmawSVzQAW1NlxWRTg06A3Q1kuuD5QN0APJflMICNd5KA7OkrY8DS4sOq32GY1oG@1AfxANpQS0WZA8JH5QMKZjKk/meDjo3adiaZzecn@9hMF3OsdC35HoT0p/SjPQkrH@xMKGhYR71lumJ0h0pX5ZoYU1otdeAIQQU1sR0QRdPjDQUmxeCZsnuhpWfTedMg4qoWfh4o5HnriaFQQekiFP0kqDMqU8RUBTRHC8SSPp7OHQBupjKXPiDIRAE@SA8UwdUAgMnUkdoaOiDVgIFve1qrBzyLpTO4XOSD0HT2EBTMHSR7suNljYWRq0@yoVTaC8JiPIgiiS06iwcGV0RVnQigxg8GPI5ZsftzEJteEWEgCISm0koKeO8LOPumYc5BCoT00CLIZAxvB9DETlChhIHLVbuos3paptdE0GY4EWgj//UcZ2CvwTihOb1hMwWckj61xnvOoYHMknasseaY3N3UzSaIZRv6Z9rNId0aNrXRVIUozGvDKzt0AwpYx2YVGLk/DoHropGODQKTwjcROBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2bRPEOCJWTsdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKo8um2UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6T/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyNrkSpI9sXFp@BaR9dTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdlCJBLoy9oBQYVo/cX7iYR7E6NtsIR6VP2iCqXKyt5eoJ5UIWzyw@YyDqQLIBdBIfgCcSq1TQGYtJ1VuoaKrZmaz9Jkrnk5alDQQRXig3CvcLKuSIDFp/gNNISy3jIPs4TfoVC0ZBUFpbvagVubzIXNYv7y7b8cv7SAJTx8pKpQmVgvyi/VTXMocwXMYuVtaScj0Wu8jBINmsRDKR5Wi0mNQhIyUW@64Yiyuc2tGIClI7enkZAaIK@ly0ehbhGyWysZhHKigHDsygE0Yjqbsi5N@M1WPxCKSNRRIwxahEIkCZFhLBpkojZ04Q6PD4JSfMZjweIjY0rWv8zoh9CEvBBIsn3wH@3TyZnPb2r0G6spatoyqStLg2At70Mg9s08PTuNbYHmmsBgy3UAMYbdvezAhn48aQ9GdSbs1gRjQdRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOIO9oIJgjQ78euIoTjN@pCmzDhNHU1dU6qicSg4@C0V03N1YaO@LCSatk@D4DeA86BrrSgY0@iu5TYJSAEPk@n58fEyjOIp1UlmtV8qY4wsLQUA@nX1khrH2p2D8kLmhVOJawOUBVVdtANVKLaHmvBmN8FSqsjzeE6PPDRCSbZVexoDLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5doAaDg3WzDfUUFzwFg@eWTbxo1mmQYSObUNqIHhy9gGU8jnkRfYqFbby249TN95yIFiM8FygLZBrNPEbdktljZM3eyabBkAkDVTKc7YewaaSkDnc2B6yWztExGo1jWN8RQPqjjc26gjyoWcp30rCJkm@NQVyBo2v9I@wAN1Ptl7vw0jhJzPZKD8ri9DH6@SASzTdcTAFvMBhMlWR77BlnyvDnrjCYMS8gefRQI/mSrvmHxer8CACqUSPfwTJQ12ch4C/dyNaruueXXfJg0JTRnBWcZE7UEZhH4qqsO7DdQwPBWMoS4pJpDONLjfvjsgO097QzWktnomky5Bw8hWWbqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UiZcxLJkzIIcccglbXVnWtrzl7ZO7SDVRd/GHZjUWrnY/gSFOdkJhv@OIVTVK@rDW6HH57hAOSHVLpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHtpWWteawMFttdEHxVNXbYlNf8LsWAVkIv2na/3YNJ0Kb65rnX3xE8Y0bvL9rcb@3sZx7fgdLwShsbX@UFewKGtLUwCY/ISi3V4VsAN2LLPvaeS2aIilHJJenbD54/RUxK5g7FBY/APhBQzvoxU/1Qp1Wy2WNLnXCxSAqwiIln0aw7rxOEKSpd8LFJBFQonW/pTVdANLGOjZ@Scs4D66efEPJxKY7@TMPSK3jaE9CNTsTpYp/MbpdHDU9oKzFHydRFbX/eAcBfN1gkkLvSDLTNRcYA/fCuHj6wtz8c1EzQX28OU5PlyXmI9uKmYeqIesQMhwHWMurqmIOYAeplXCFFz78OOKFPfQwofIa270g4k83CXCjYsjPipaKhFBLmCWc0efL1zYDbSR@jySlSdiMYovd7BkGyYn6wiC/PIZF0IgCLQ4e9BOOSPHR5ELokiCzsGXQbx4zgiy3lAa0Cv90rohgSiW1EGAyQU/cd5LbE4lNTU/2APn7ZrVGyAChoEu7YYEo7xEvAnd9ZZgp8jyFrTMwTjQl@@ynPh9TYiTQO/KcXKTHELtyJqI5NQeuGsuE3G8W/J1lsYVN9Y1xDILtgsXhKcw9O6boDDtazatfgYlY8hT7C9Dkjs7mVDDJT8m61sJWfJmvnlTCiIimQ1i9drESbHvamRSch6xeCj61/psyg7olvQzATpTqNkYPlb0mx36mQOwJixnMCziUhBS5QVa/9G4Z4Kmr94SGNkACBlQSzOU9DE90BowrzyTdo2JwjTVzhCU4DRM0tD9BbBkqUiQnWZTewgU6IJFd59zK3k8hIlINrWSkt1ZD9oRYebDjRKne4cECP23N2MMYxNN4QwtB1KJ53/8WRuaZLbBesqYpgKeowGUJG7pPNh@Iil66Gd@WxPM1VDXFCIMub6EsqXg@oOie475qFGnYclkT7H6qHGL5gZ2xR/ob49wHi@5perDtuo@52dCJJ40ufHUhtanGsETp4w0QX4g@ZTBkKenSZduKm3CwqdGmkqJLGx93i7qiE8SAro3SKevKKdr12P@QprTGzpD/otrZ19qV22A3/lUWZtkskxeacpq2rSVpqY@wgeWcj1sm8nBdZcqjUUrzIH1699EM1SyoyvX3NlA53wC8CpaWrerWu7zIbDbHmj7NE1J39LjEVZxdS1G2rPyGE5L578Pgbi7VzzHw3TSdPr5FoYkFmlBr0HS4gJ5MkAmbYqwutIc43St9@2chRmSEguCp9KKxzM5HHW91RB/KX4weDg9DtWUvlSan5ovzXOSzJvEpPmSfJKbqqjOYpH@C70exjKtr@jJbDvgfFCsu2ZQ3zUHlObuyZau2MBMjmgO9Qaaj34eY3AcnlrIVr7rEfb2i@Muij20viJ6qejJLVPXbOzO@kNidNok7eeJmyPox0@KvlnCtkkvtntJzzVfEpgtBxc3HmC0r5BsfF0BV24CnJMyHyJay7zF74PaRs@8Ufnv/NHu09xSfYWMSurEElprTvJ260t8isvj9DOfitdzS@W09Lnhwog/OTP4Wk62Nd20YYqOv48RApRt2@a/83k4SDNNMZJkaw665ycThRqwlLCtPdCSit419UKxm1bg58HmHlodlPvi@bXyzpNXsvxleeWqRaYhi@eDgv46bV1/iRPIIG3hwlXA@cgoO09oiQWPhysI0wlcjZ5fuZ1MkVKm0txe8lADWK3erTJ2nz9hLHmIuu5YMhiTmg1aHyYoFcHhWFz1/im5rTyeW/vrBNIM2tUvVSLQuNe6CkMX/c40Kctm5G9MIWcyXy@eOvpQHapz1bvD5pWK@xEfmXx8faEyohpLwrKYBuKhXdGD@iQmkV9Vahy10feogFF0DTr5F3WbufJuAJr4AOfdR@A4Qsdswq4xHEw07sTkzTh@nHK9gduzzfZEITHmWyVS8csa1ISybqv0fUix3@6bMFU2@6A0GF/R/gIpGUH47wRiCvHVjAlbydzsvdVt0GRB8YAW1a7tJJrJv07oZB@a3xNwqQTzNUN1xvj7EKXnCdGmaerf0jIgS9sa7TvWk7jT9EstNKPkiI0OzLdk2GgVaXYesmHwcUZMLYF6OI12Hpk4By1Tj8wFZ6zsj4xWAZv7l2aXMFKTkci2Wq77IYYkW4icKqZWH2VHroOaTVVX@GNUWHkMXymVexSfp3UI5ZbWaHBdh6/k@Eth4SnRMxgDsbQ2zEx6al8l7yMqvdK@Gtru40GgkYnfOdGpNK1LPJBuoEFfN/B3YtUooA05pgFzKUexuipORnRczhShD8lXd7ljLnH3@kpX5ccSHhMdvk0Cd8DxKZzvnG@dWOObUlqQjK/ZP84K0HGu1bHtPucifDVuQXsO@182sk318RYaQ7/YqVPpuas8X1D3jJ7ZM3pqz6LO4fke6h7AkQ4/UPJYJaD8PcW@xi1/JI/8uVzPDlJXN3X9a6iL8pBLR9Ocb6fdxu36bUj6TXjHShMixOOLBjwYsolINHY/1Hd66hBGJtt0zIGaJN9DoDqaevjvfNPz3mHEZueaarX5fgW0@ymO1tRVdqtBEa7s4CL5fDNSUzcV3FX6iPIOlHGfX2OYapnWF60eXcV0BgN6NAb60KYfMvAmO/Mtl2tsh0r6NcygOXyrCGdZtWs2Wz3tS0VqqopjaNdp14LDvY/OS4UwppprLLmFwSldA1pZ4xQyQSUYf4KPvYfGv8CKztzabw4ta/xlwTC5AcAztPIFA3Q8lL9Yq50TTUM@7oVy9/w8smohlnYf5CZSoFFZTqoZ0ErkB@0/E9u@hPSiNcYHlJ6pelNhAstq32K4FHsDyISnBfY3QPg848VDgnBXyDeYFUZ3h1079mXG7bVBp8KfuQhrXTxhxReWbN28DZiZoesrhnjMHZW9RcjHVkTyjy6JpNJi6TOpDh@0benawOa/LNnJzsUyu5Y/CzWeP9MVzdNWO3yRAl1f0uz6poV730GFSLYs1W6hvRulL5eKXOQYZhekcFJnPrALO7cKs9sH5ukmkyNc8u2B2lVwL9y@htvidHt20APM0zsJvgbx66Fia6@HpqPOxTm9o@BrUL5Sulprd6IVXIQudcXGKf6Y6AQYNNsQtz3Npi3IrmN@x@FsRovzs5HTJnXvKNzjhpCAXiR2grLkHnN3jHoONOpjvDI3r0mtU6zLPyjoNIcMpuI5t57zd188ZkW4HfYHQ1s85ufexwMFQbtx/5rC7VsNpGDyIwhd1lN0Z75tOWA8BX1KjIS@8yEt@72mm132vphhoH6BgEOl@wHG2oBx@UhxoAcYc5iV8v/KVUu0TSS5UmN/BEZQcyypGZrzuB3GcRSYB7lPrBBXtfDATHoff1PPvhVD8nQ@VfYflfgwpI9bOsxsvgR19O4LEOrmYwB888YxnR70zpnYCbE9EsI0Sxxys1PuSdIwbSWlUyfuKQQWxrMwQxwaHdNKMYKLRpV4PBYL8US4uNA1AMyForN8eM6HHxO0ma7ZDsFqHXZxwZbuRmuZNfmeVZi0JrF6nWPFD5062R4N6CDeMU9@saTUK0uRZDKyFLk01lgm4oGrOnSyueDKBGxHowcvr08CZih8wzC63RqX@Tkmu0dnBEGhbINiemaQvQiVXH4ahx/1OsXtDP/hr9ri6CTMXm3Q6GCgA4LgyWGzr/bM26c8X5F7bTBQ8Ogl4gCZqPODQMnNGoPOChosPzFp3rKzndOiOIcljimD54hrOF4peOOiDQV3UTu88XhpvB2xImMvlVuplqkP@wbMGdpOz06xE402SA8tf6cjuBDMcCycOLUTbI@1VVw0pn3vZCvQTfOaDrBgSf7DX/HTZ7T7XexKdrOnU6eBHHGTu0xHvlotcwildpF8Ui1TgESRyCAhh2iFY9hpKDyGe8LpWBxwZNI9FEbZ8JNhm7UTltxmETyBjWdNylonulQ7fv7mIlOv/MD6afU//iwduxOEk75Llgq2lGAuSPkeGSsYnYdoPzbCpKWRxDP0jgZo4mjALW8PIJHCmQxPB7g8ZpoD0WvoYC@dY/W4UVwwEUU3tbN7OqxPZ4KJYdVbOh1GW3INHDnwsK1hQwcDb4xQ815XWYoOubEoeeKwPGSIJ@wUcPFTxLRZHk86YZKlEfvMeshkyRZu4AYfJ6SOh@v6lQ13X1EuuPsrvaU2h7TB4SabyuYqVJ2lRmW9Si5LbZt4yPXi@8tRNpO8HK1u19O2S9TLy9F3mexboLoJ89ilJ2nsedsHW3dLqWrm82dbGTNJuo@U@W41EBNLd0d7R9snp7XTsxNohXtX/OyYVl/xZQ1yEW3J7pk6HR8Guliaan@D/PF8AB6NsiWFrePFGLFYKLjbmEAFraWktMSdAdE0kfoLyeelt9VA/CyAkGkdjbkctQfDALYhMBtSDSs/HOAhaCbSioOcxGUaynjsQB5hcE/gHFlKpJJYBYiVBGJ9JanYw5V9ysO@hmJfxPI42Z7OBUGKefldePG8inNJcP87qfcABsrfvt4cy@P1JphH6g2gXqibZqe2t392vD2ZDHiMniR1K6W82GbPhTP2NG5nck@u0okkkRANbRWJSZSAe8VgRreeNFXnVoVqCeHY6vPExKFUfinkMyZQpoJXx9TLnBbRKJUAdZAyVmvqFEBHGwWK6I7RAXR3vIqeENiRPNRuwVOSwBymazxS@HGrgVgFudyud0RCXMjriB1UfxJuj8Oq4RgNOjylemCo8kYdm8F/YFRyXdk6GzExnMl1lmRZ@OoqzF97HmyszMcotsQJIS3xskteefEKCShT@0qh@S7tPxMHHWCU1pUBnlcX0Acwx1xjH4cmnapyhYmnX9zibErht6VQ07YUrA2d1jIcPHvujluEb2/npILaGVfNSL4HeW5o4EAFQIG7S7ZHMFECZuuQrOe3IHCSm@LAvTtUkgHUFgdsPS3BZjeaTQZSbIQO6jg6SEqsjag4XhxE5@lYTbdBJ2nD8M2v2SHlJEW7pvnW6aTBpDDwZMpTGRNMCiGsXZk9gA1D6W0LhtUPPPESwRFmO4Azsr6YTALluprhXnSzhnZcMnCtMcca4m6DamQmiVuENXIle05fDwDOuYriUk3/@E//nF8/cemA@xfCPcpsgO@PhK8D7n/ixsgy@P6Z58uC74@57/s0NtnsmXuRvTC0PrjFHPjymTRTJ5QJ7m0/VBevtbGl3@wdMZuMzdiWfWUUaCaUMMhzmgH00vrAFDfUxgjOc/Cb0McTvXgDLAJ8BfyB6g1qNJSfatWjePJ6LZ3GguOMOEX7ktURtzTTQeyPQ7yABJSwdCFfWJHTUMjkjYuQTkN2cSMsRxiLrYFMDN1og8qHZgsPPDDJbim6WimUOW@kl5Tvc9IHr6BLABviE4ULBmnwjISXAuKqIll0SYnLMUyKA1lEjqBMa5uc1UAbjJIDQGIYbLjHyUDdNAWpgI8NdeSQxjR2J0BNvGgKLWQqv4bGRZQERBw3XpMx3R39ra14NiDQQVPBZpDOEewEwdakecx68T27dC6NurguhQHj/WoO6xrg/sdz7lDhnIXnQ2cv74hOX72BtWHPTgwTt0DvQGlZNJvO5tJyIRbgUEmggvJiV/8MKKFzg7BoqdqVObBrm9t7Lw6PTmYuoSDIyDRYhEWq6/HLZCpxUfccEa/ck0Td2EmfvNrYcUkZLJW/TwAh/M0C08Wcl9t0SR/I/ZzvKZ7NmyJmMpIzX4uYVuaSO7SXZha7H5sOAG7yLY0zuUZjd/cX9fXqpRGeyf7zvIt5wqllZC5wXdp0LU9kuphYxD13p/QpXvhnp9wzNFnJv3bKO/nD/X7ww9dIeNcH@ndJuHuyQ3TK0zvkGUo9sFsb6p5K86zoIgVeMLe8IGvcospYVD/DVmhmr0ewNEzUZfamQ3GMySPSIbchuffU2RzSJuHMrUx0oYtHMw/u1MWIXd@/3UFca9CD0ulaM3QrTuC6h8C807cpe6BrTjQWMgTE9HGwWUj70UsSPDClcjFi3rkmG3XGUYoshVG6g@i2HuJ3TDD3Kog43SZxNAS6HZkD5lvRtlTXdQw6FdsaQhYtnJC9GPYBrkOPYxVHCxW0rCQkBnpG3KJc4P0JghKpfjsfHcVSPXXU1row4kRjCRBN38myfw@FghcpgF7VnFcDNEsNegrUAZsmt47XOIxi6yXy@hXk9kR2Oz/YqIcAGSZtxta45SJyZrhXBmHDr7FIwqNMM5aIpBifSYnbgGi9mgxRKbbZw919ZProdDRS2YKnu/lg3tGsfgprBcMMZ6HnuLc3yDXfdCVIgDLKhZLSjLY6iuLp67U60gnCI7fnN5GYNMPidC@JuIWiPX1BiSsLFUcIJf9yjyl5Vyp5cm5SNJRKqZ4dwhNyMCmBHE8cax@coCJEO31lwKJDuuHFZilG3uhl1EjYjhVjySoO17fMYPE42TTgQREwZ0HQDrk0OkofxQvRoukKNBKG2kYbH5@0AbuQU6k6uCmTGFtCe@YmaFNoCYyFYI4KSdYILegX8LeGJeLXV6bENZZLlG2ILlkAqLnRJKe6PZIvQAuqNas@8U@0BwQMp2qptCZaY1LalxjwxfocgQho50hxd44A9BUnmoBqKKMBatNS2xrIy2cvVcNQgUDAM328rVMZApNZsYR7kWzCv@iNcgjzIu6KI1JQ0MkL4LYjd7oJ6tpSukymsfI9qDUfLlGv6QjNZpz@b9OpdPkuuqRXxmnQNWPV6FKvIsdzy/H4krEcXTJQ23ryBC1q90ugzDVSMEEdAVBySY@VgZ9B@assGeUlZT261K5klykFeGGKfAcJfrDTqbsl5T699ASUpQSEWFzoRJdsupslk0rJ91A@7CFL6QTwzB1eMkLXw2L2S1o8jmVILTWwAD@kL0/iNGxenqTJeFcWc4F0ty@625Qq5rXEzLW2nIAieM0bsPI4YIkNbw0X2L/@LTcv7gH1j2f8ErcFM9rNoNrByZc0GfP1gkXIaZS5QshE@eU4QMBRFIiI3oQSi4Ew@c1vwnKBMelpIRc140/zmXI8kpdhmg7z6/Az0MPTy5Il3V1uJW@YmoxcdJR86mP96Pro6G3sMspKLBLePJTkFel7Vsqyr/ussuwDH/bbfMLh5XQonF6Wn6ym0x8@fIAZB3wuqqkqiA/@iV0kI/WL6Cpj1dXV5UShuJx4FmkEChaLZrOxE5Zml5qmDex2G75mj@5yjob55@lTygum//DPeJjIXzhcD4KI0PC3win5MLtcVZTl@Er2mVGGopXwk2MyOPG3CF@Z5fNsGz9/@7//7Z/97Z/Q35/R998r7Jp9gs91h@E/uT@1A24F3c3OJ7y7BqYWFZILg0gkn4ucfB9h/9k@i0yuPl39T39y@DHshKvZ9LkFTyf8MVwohrkTHODLub6bcDW8jmCF@/A4XalUwLn6n/5XSF99AXgwZrwOP9W8i6swDleTFUryOVwtgEPOZiHf//tnPwuFq6Pwp7Asy@Ex/TXCGRk/xSfyE8bAkZZWi5JpPnPLOwp83LC0LGcv/fYMNDc2rRfcg3ygXZkZngQlt8dVTHADOb4FDm8rLiw@@7DFmApDLX7W1p7NEHx/yn@cSsInJbrBCD3JkVuFcLGSaPDsPV4NBxxTFfZ@mai75/9GuFDYvXIzeaF06hNUvwzLxZXDZ6Ov/jC/0C4Rwz7tvMzZdJhLdc/D3E7PvgUuFP6hUjl28O9VE/@OTvCPjX7KB1A/hc8i/NE/fDwv/i5SiAgmkNnP4m/RXUPhi/BFvf66R38W/u0a@Nf8iH/7n/DvtYN/py38O36Nf6fv8Y/NVCYUXl9fD8fjx6AaCp79ms8ZfFOphvC5vIvofqcftnJYOHwWYuFkPZ68v79IfT@Kl8viH5SmsufDD3dBser3yeT699V4/IKKd1EV5VxP1qtQVl5k@vl@HRDH1y/W11ONarWarH9fvVifTCTSPXsWx376DBJW6xcXofAdtkUFf5bxp2Xjb1aS0uTFwQJG5xK4GDnpIQIY3baP/lD4w/qHaPxp/GlGz9xk5Gv5@pV56P8fHo4gQhtlrkwr08v05DZIRJZRzzLjzHiU6ZuHchucKvxl@uDUMp1RppsxMoYsj0cTqB7@7x@azqtDE7CZkNIZZRxEnOnAs3t4@ArwdSDvK/jTMpnMCAo5ytzAf0ZHQU0XedHz@0bsMnTBpA8qjP4pOZLKRFKFSESr5wuDj5d399nCRykRaVxeROrlcNq@vExz7YhlV8p0jdv9faOxfbDVaKSRj9aX4s/iyWfwqVTj6@LxNFwtP71cS2L7cf5LNcLp9aeX1VwS3YU4NFIWwtbT8W/8@CjhWV28DMGE7/wcv@e3N7fcRQ5yXZ6fe7H4k8YgclEQfAA0PTf9hIOBpvl7@m8f/pf1/@qMRS/qMcaid/frUfrE8C8Wu7u/uxe/1Vg0KjzRdfjDAPBjkrv7KjoJ6A5cF9FYPXZ/z8PgNxpb5wirmMd6lRL7gNBhwzzXy0gZNLzKUlQsql1ejjKZWLkJIZ55XflM6zOxMu1cWWrimhrMBuTlGIHkV8rlFeFeLZbLReGWC4VyedmDyoBHOAFItZVWGRm9HI5hETj3RzNoU6GrMiPRttrBO9OfDgYwsZNLmc@fvaBGo61ZjQaG5z5/voSOFMF9K5VSHkIyxc@foQ9GYjDpOzDFimkJpnByOotOGZz59fXCSrVaWAF3oRiLlaUlvpkl2o2X5Nj9UlripYNpViQsouTiaoxC7yMYz8Lr7GkVGNfGD7u7DxMR2Uo@Fm2O1RhbKUSL8ZL4qyzG2Hq6uszE38VFLr6yvLr8rF73ByHs6@U7pSLfV@6UNZzp35db4rpJ3EmoPHmSK0HtipnyZajR2Kqd1hp4b78koSAdMIahJDZCuEQ4sCIXZJfJl@oXWPD6ZSSyVn7Gm6eYZ@FIWcAlIyCAWLFE9QvD5E/r4B7iEcpn8V2Tl7O5xXR@9F1hOwPK8udl/FxcXBSzxfgyCKjlUqler1Po50VKc9Efdep0o1EleSEX8vUkaiFXo84yFFZezYWXQwPaELSaYW1cU7XQzrUIgT3FZk1c/rZVXXev@Lw1Lb19q7VVwH60X9vcPk1k1wFldqe2mcienG2EZfTmfT9F59B/vF3bOjyDBEf727WT7ed7b7bPjiDchrEOiAWf/pGiDtWGejsc3qK/odJnU7OVqytlMGgM4DPq/Pirn//4q//ux7/44x//4uc//sWf/fqXf/Zz@P4VfP@YP//435by@PvrX/6z//nHf/0XEPjv4fvv4Pt//PqX/@Jn/Ev@v4Hv/xkI@xvxDcDxL5ASsP3Rr3/5J3/561/@k38J338lvv9y@vvjn/5v/P//En/o/Isf//Rv8Ed4fv7HP/7hn/z4h3/w4x/@4sc//IeA/O//@lf4/yd//ff/7lf4/7/8m7//6//h7//ofyLHn3PH//Ov/i3//bs/@Pnf/eE//7s/@OUDvz9/9PeXXxH@y99DyNeX82vwfE29vjXklz@pPL8NNfxciMH@7B//@C/@EXDun3Lffw8@@PeifuF5vJg4zdCScT/wF4x9ToMOlHn22QMFlP8jhkIw@zyJjUIzbuivf/nP/xKDJ2D/URBDRp6FXUJgL7dfAOy/9goWhP3Fj7/62Y9/@Q9//NWf//irP0KBllwpJWqJpPwFWw4A5r8CDgELXwMHgPI6LmsvssVQFhyL62h7CMnxDx@ApIvgAl16OZTPgS8kV8ktoxsSwtRkmU@O4zjlh@8otFICH1oD4jCExHlUHKI24qxSqcRDowrEESh4Mc2IVYs4/0H1vwJ4MRFPk2gUQbVkow3CAikr8WPWWK6MeMI4BlQJA8MCYdCxJGeleLGyBRlWRlsMcSHyeOgDPD9UqsXKqIrofqAiAI74BmQJUBUs3aj6A/grhBPgQ6OtH6AoxUo8Xi1CSIWqSrklGpSnnKfKUd3jjOqN4YyhMezpM8a@k@SixKdhQEomoPE37kM/JWPEU4i/jC@L6tC/66TvMqaHdhoRfXgYj3@KwZReAADeZBK3QME3mcTSPIPoEUcVp2zhEecYgHJxYbXxAmiUjYfi1L5x8kD@UIav@6xXAx5Eh9VZWloC13pVykmHoM8z63rNdhQLVwhIpVljUqEkYTDuKFGXjkjjX95ahl8Z/rcXaVcoJ8dyaCmCQ3mEuXkk4zlzxQxT6d2qUV2WqeRxgguF/XCuZdIyD6iHKywWitKd1TGaNqoD0GBCr@zuhjkCVTAhSQm5UOLWUjGrfGeurVV@kFdWQ/Ak/xCvyxYXN0Mz4CuUUti7kKDVu@Q69TRwgrpRCFWrYqmKyaHqyfYpJDg9ZHI2k2KgP96trGZX8iv5bK5QyK9m5ZVCaaWQL@ZAQhUy@WxWLq2slIql1Xso0DPo54m15WZ@vfoPZj7/zT@Y95kfip9Q9S0bpdjR0evkfag6SibTWSpyRc6vlscVKAgFhaqkSXFVeXyXBKUTmyd0Sbui7nADDhQtdJdEVl2ADwsthNgCBMEHMKOhnonV473DslhGw5cR8KU0Sc4DM8RCl8AMHFtoMPEJYcs9AXHzRObOfMF3ZtB5iqdsDiADaAeD7eN@RcdkpybfF7ehtkLr4nxINRSiRYcLoGo9hFd9X9RD62kvdj6mzR5/QdemZYKO@tNhNhTjmkdtaXilX8vxonYVvLrH7mtO7wGIs0Efz5Oo1u8Nw3a/CQVEmyMH2IAfSzfNeQCr7OzogVq@8k7t4eodHdsD8OO957ungefpdm1zN1RgG4cHW1OPvADKs/3tnVPPu8pj3aR5D8W77f39aa944DxjkeVXEwkQkPCDzwR96Jla@t4FkVMPj5yZBGuM1aZ6wm@oH3V005Yjka7aZ9B5ZXznV9fUYQK1lNnM4HICTn8aajY/ZksgBEsyCMOClJcKmSwMMXRXfsco44b4sL1SLuXk@HFUXo2tZkr5llXZGBYdR3q6KMGsMr1eLYZe4SYvQEKHFTQ7tAtTlz5eHI6nzJ2QpbZhGnNr0DmMJr6kZzhgDwbCA4PQaWndHsjEW9MFCDUVhcH3Wz@QXg1@nMcDHJ4Hhc3E6HPAcVlL67BMKEXGqmypmC@WctliolgqruRhhpdPyNmEvFpcLWUSckYuyoViviQniiul3ApIT4jNl1ZDYZAwWiedhsFBliR6akYLL/dcx1tSzVSvGgrzyT6MyPj2ubDiBQyLTMoVLzOQTgrhBlamVRYlfL9jBt@eCAgV1mLhnZ3NzM6OJG2gBw1zmxlJaqMnX8xkVjckSaWYTRDwWUkyeRqIAjCHezKZjU1JGnIEeCBRknro2S6gJipJGno2azs7mM8VerKYHsCueQz36K5nFcAM9ORypMpK0kcPHcDVeEYrVNJt9GCeGLPDYzYhTpKeu@XJZADDMYfjGHbdutZqkrTHPbUaxrygiud5UV@ip0YfSbLAAzwoSV1wdC2Yc0tSE5zIiZLUAldrrEBYH1x4ftFwFEkacwIhiSRpRNBK61oCtUuEYza7u7tKz2mrXf4ZW/zZgqJBjDYabu80nz9vdrtNa1zbfn6MMS9e7CpX46HV7DZFsmYDPiakgZjr/nj6A2XcazQUfW7MS4gxpmIa44aKZWsoH6FM4tPFTPqNFxDzAmLmrXZwbPDpA2gTPxt9eG4oTYpxPxRDz1GzKZWRR53xQEVjCnYZ2ghUDob0lZZlltEFejpbjEQjifGFXE98KlMM6zMWjd1lyvcI0onSqxtQhsbuxhejSqYOurlcRjEXXew/leRSXlpbVJ5GR@guSGugna9IsTV86YXZibBIUn46LEqFVWltGZ7SUykHzlE0E8kwBj@xi9X6U2kVkUhPnyYlKAl4AUSBhNJqCRGWVkFLKN8DNRwQw82hozYa0eitqlzHYrxG/EU57Pz8PHbHtz5pVEOn3ImOEqMKLw3TYuVPUPhpTG0VhsNhyzEtjq8L9f/0NLNGlYTsixLknk7H1lEaofyAp2@CRkOyZ3wOneORBTqu6O5tIQXYXgudoqpIL5FjeIi3ie9doROiMAfhtwnQW1JUUBxLoVBV6E2n6shJ7aq4z6SVTJ5PfNbXzwEOT5riMcGDYZ9tsFvKBQ8NuPumG5UNQJkpG3jqXUXv0ig8ClXbiqPADGrjbri2JmDvy93KBSL4jD/rSem8ei7VWTDf/GoGSnVmtLKr6@sXn@ugPgJFx2EYArPF8ihM50JWV8pRmK3EKrb6kSuRn3U0@y02KhmuTi7Zw/5FZrEgJ@6SjeS9rtjOkryaXbsYLl0k5friYuZzd116X5XqmD1qmfQXtE2C0C9DmNsgfJgId7QPEM/WkvzFHXKxEEvh9vWG2WnQ5fzsQ2A08BMOyqAO6CroRHIpWxYgoYHgnKjEovjWHb6PJhqJrGYjkVikDFCLEEwMGLsjfokAF0eeAO/CaATMW8pCvKU6Q1CToE@5xfRKwJXrghwK34famj1gK6VQ@C50f3e/XnW1kJdsPFbiSdf7hLFuHOZZaVo1wfWWRXIlU9VnrFapdY9rZQFa26TZUDrELvnprGR68VvXZuLr1e/58xLX5SCbECcOLV@m1@PVdLVavQxJkhSWXMt6tJiHKRTaGX4I0y16bPOuMzToZP3aKySXssZ1qot67IcDTb8r5pJVUtCj0Nnuw/H1NK75pappIlbrkFbEQ2HDFE400DrQOaCD5vMSztdUNjgpfb/6ffH7V2eHZ4c77FlmrbhW5JSgLQrPEgk5IkeAss9AL9COt0PhwWczL/9gvCiH1waR3EokN6H/XVbE2eQo8kH0Alci4Fu/gLlYPQauSiX7VC5k10CHC1fxhGR2NVwlh1xYDdfDPPEKxNb5trSsHK6mRbC8KsfCdpL7gJ/zYRsav/jqw2eYQ4v3gWpZcqXTokRL9@v38F@9v4Bp5j3NNu/pH3/S8HPPAeAfwT0Pf/ifAFwQxo@v/5Bc5//r9LN5yAstFYDa4Q@VKjTq943vG@FQuBSpxtMRfLe12Echpm@owi0b9Kfay/j3vR@wbNv2sucD7/oyy1dlxtTldDp9GXudBW2vVCoUC@HQb2Y/6WWYai4v1FiEX0bDhS295N09gBOZeLEYWgiWF5JbJ4ebL2EiDtJWNfAFi2zz8CCFUfgOQP8EVUtXFUsfi5cAjhEKhfTp5hG@Jvxs64jSnNPZOQolQ4DIZWmvvSbewZG4YXIqx7KZTD6dWUnLeSYX1zKra9kCU0Dc2HhWXriWMCmjam2agzHX0aObMUq8UEMYjNvXYF5lq2vs@dE@paBj9MsLW9uvDtnhwf67lBvKw093907YyeHO6XnteBvq8Wr7hEm1E7Z3IrHzvdPdw7NTVjt4xyD6uHZwurd9ggjSIRRVqDNwgnkKM1u3x3YaFQqbtOaJYNtsXavOZLhiDZQ03q04GWzgixdUvJ18MnxowOS0HVTIT2oLfHxmiF5pt60QHtrTWmwBtfGFZdXCna1SL2Ovsvzw7aeMlV9krZWDyCprZQ6M3Poq0zPij@kr/dwxW1xcvDQkT84Hq@HNB4JBuN0bwvwy7b3fXogWVtgyzAKyKzE/5uDwaCHj@hbOj08XZC/ueGsh63n2dhZynmcbfCueb@d8ayHv@TZqLxcKfrKDzYVVz7e1vblQ9HzApAslH@fB1oKcCbnEujG19gK9XCq6s7e/zZYBKFaeiEXTDDqmgoEQ0aFh8xsUaAK0vHzbMxOkTjbHU9Bt9UvQLvgE1ALqIxdI13qCLZsD@OmrfQCGZCFPw1OsbishsOI9JDB6hO5CC1ihBawQwC/g2V2EY4sVlo0xiF7o8NXmKL@XKsGkM5tO6H1ns3XUCqrADAm62IROakIKVbwLLrRwL1BGO2S@6tD2UwIFpZlJlhSL4fGug7P9fZ7ZALIwrahEkIw80hyc5gCwQRXhF6sOobxxeLNQWyCtFoTygO@rC91PtGZoujWRFFDPhYUWIJik7o2iJxiqWQlc/0S86OHbxgEYosGdARc/1xaNtrCuXdVpUYFiSMztwx1eQ1xBrbDJVo4xzJQoRdF8Q/rnz8z1XTqTXmvSa0Q4boGcF4vj4yWtIGwMwxbcA4UEQYenKeUCckw8DqmhOhQXqNcCEB2@/Ky1W8oqZJSJsCdPqBzr4CtFKAtMF6ccWRJBEIEgGJEPkXlFW6TixhbSy7hNgb/sGYmI4wi/6rA59u6JAMk6XdCpVvV6odecCwbMUMpTAllEddrY1uDOZRvgR/EInJxgTegmCeZGygWMxBlFgqkJ1oHgKZna0AzgXNXyZaLLCtAZqfUPtngL8UtRKJwHUI1B7q1Rg4GweILdlxh9YaFpwTyt7EKBPCQo4FtkmigSgsM9nu54i5It8/6CbImpvybl3s6ay0c8NbCD4DQiK85XOK@I6lJg1QeawS@QYf@tAHrOkhxZPC4gPC4TYNuTcMkkh7t3@fILldiersXiN9cCxfKDtdj@ymr8drWAYc1nEagFiPgo4I0DNP1MtmZ2HgoYCwkF1eanoYAB1Ocl6OMTCL4iPQy5fvrkt6eHQXptuitDv4UW5FKBJ5n0tia97Ukvdl8IURhMCbIr7DNroksugAvPM7MiONpcVk4m7Ex6yeBQYaqbpuNJYJ4D8ByKSg6GDDgrjFGCpGy8ll3p46tBKqy209g72D6djEV8KbshCt7DF2VTHrFJMFEgjLej6Il5JYp2kAhc34we8TwSRM/Gyenxdu1VAsoXY@t@D5jWAeBH9ISJGty7OUCoobZgPG4nWPSkxpZj7AmWLMGETQA9X52FbtoqoHowx/ZwkKWsMhzE80/2pDD2yNCcrKQoi8bY58tLGFIzq0zuDz7n@jljNddm49wqKrscj6eDCCnvCpgD3jW5soGQwJ4K3sgxN7OrTIatWDnmqD3QuEcZaxY/1esexzYaFt1TlwOTJmV2md61jrJF3FEB4@KkavO4FkljI/IBhmI3hjAczsmqFSf9HNmTYl0Fi5elrX5rWb6k0U6WJcnLsk6ZzpbhN8KwB9Ol0NTJWrrqwxw4AwUPn4rIwwHaTI4wyAqFuC0lcONT1MQXMjixNbqpA2VKo4GX7zUaUVvVO/jC5qHVgiEf1WVbgOEHY1M8kjoSOiYjBXlQf5qMaGt4WBTvSIRRZwohvTe6QvfLRSnHUMgrme2oAypVoBhoDsMXlwYzhAn2hB@aFQ9xBUocWxNa8Y6C/cFFdjFxSQ/HMbR7iTnBIJ5nQz02nRPnsc2cOLyLbV4S93DxnLirYX9eCUAwPBAjjgfOiTHMw3kJ@B03fkT9IkDAiyCB6/VobH7TQ7@abPHAJUVE/1NrqIobd/YOAywIyqXgwEBbh7dUYNqWhtdcTyPyDihDyugoFjgr7bFVzOckxW5p2jR6F5NARIf96CZnNlpr9QDrd3K2GEsEEAYw4iV6fUV/CCcLIIUSzkES5u8oZ66V0/ZQIwtO4/XTp/Cov9GG6Z2fwBw8Ao@xPiw2vgu8gLc0eTEeM8/pcj66tVnGoXC0wmPzyxP3WT0E7VZCjgUJ@ttmn/zW7JOB/LFP/qSsK@xishz1eMC/BgF@Hd0O/pMycks9mVvsm2oc5BpVvX6AffHekUA2/L6ByWw9NEICeTzlVoXQY8BXCgnEFUT0DfKFmk@chp6X2h9/lissKXtpuMTzewOZ1QOFD@FNCY0GXjHaaNDdco0GWpYaDYnnQAMvDnjBQVd0Nh6XAi21YVJsVEoqUkJKJmsnm3t7Sc2QEvzm4IpkO6alNvCKKCmBi4sViQRWA2F6qj6oSGJXmGIzSi09nEctkAdU8MuZEBDPhd4rH7w79MvZtYJVMr@iSuZUZv59hl@R2zHlhke3H8vJ4heDuRlt0t1VeBmYpWooaPidyOKtv3jJw8TdAmjSF0Xg@dpk6bPxRgdeJHo0MEy0NV6NQO9WrjCy9knuXSfSzNUkorejqQcR@JzKuU86ojenMLr3qq0KPYvMQynJv/NQFCwlahrgd1dB41dF@APa5P0norwJ1zZpoxlzqqi@YDEHWPkLCa9HgQY4Mgfw612RAm7vkhRw4zUpGOSKOnDjHSmYoiMc4roUcNGFKfAE9pb8@xn7ykjrD9FwEzyELzQ5v1g45GNNaNSnyEnpxymKECkdL7qNCryxuLQmQdVtupxl@oIWhJ93R0usHpoVsnSjMBYzoDrMQzr31pdY4nfQSAFFDEWzLUoDaRMSk7gSQmnltTpMPgO844oYVJ@nwkxu9UREUJOEl94frwJ3vFQmphdIEZg88ML4CbiVKfiGMlLuY2ueCuK3WBCKK25zyo17Oh8seBCDq6jFQo/MpP5/M08KNsl/oVOl/@8nRTNTn9/zVOaRKcw3z1Z@h9OC/6rQ/1eF/ico9L8zbf4BlXwa5WyPn1LXv6iGf7v6RTJvDMOG1b1B01v2p@hhvyNFYPWb9AC31BfyY7rAl8dnF002OKz/xFE69Jv0abtwvmPWarXTvmwdP691a73a8Tvwb2T24@dXKxtbtxvPN9q1ra3ui@7mgfq6WFvZH7x8W3z3vPPpowra@@7hi/ef9EGrF3p7PLg9V49uc2rRrg2HH/d2x87uxll/8yT/bvU2s63nOxvqxy3d3np1@vbl6fP8Sfz244ujF5/6mb591MkopX5u91Xhzeb43Ajlb7Sz9s6@dtg/aW@fZfv7W9q7nfhmZv@k9FrO7G/fvs9t3sbzmfTe4OXh8@Ozq@b2e/14b/9de/OjqRQ@Xt8O9tLtUmfz6vhN6DD3Wt79eHjY3c6Wnu@mb7c6g3Ymu6tb@au3x0cbZ@92ey@V7f5O/qz09mp8VOi9fn3jHMS7K@eF4St7JW7UXr/OvjSe39xsH4eainlq5dRz87U8uL09Mkv9VfXlwW63/9qSjfRh/k38pH96u7W9oX9cHeXO3p2/vl05eTd89frF@8OMdnLS3FYKg2Y7e3J1uhJq9XN78Zuz7bOi8rx9/rp/s7ebf7eVftVTD2rtI/36eXf3vXlytL9Xy9lDQ97fvNHfPe9dvbre2tzTzaNr3aitpPP6afvd4WHo7IXW3FJ339ovale9d@n8xvXKu3h78Pz06lPv@sXGydlhMTs6GmfMTfu4udsZbR0XssV0S/94/KljvpLPXscLN1cvstq72icnlPs0zpf29Xdq33gRb3Xfjz7q6fiZLG@@3/v07t3J7o3VrBlnH9/sHF9Zr9rGoX2YOX7x8lVTvy46V4P3xsmJ3Mo8V69fxTNKaHS2a0MbqadKfvW0v/96MNoyPx7vvbcLn@I359c5dev6@E3t43GmeWsM3hrWvtbfzLQPldob09kejp63Sjdn17v6/sdD@13o1bacz@@YHXuj82al9Db9PN65fv52Qz4ZZQ6M485KwTp48/pc07Z7b88@HbfyO28Gxb5jdF9/Outvx7f3R71PajHT1E/eXRuhs/zJ8VH21nip9Z2d3eNXBecws//mqL07lmuvVfnWWN0c57dGViF3vvXWene9awzS77SPw6OMehNvvxs4K6@1Zqf1Rmv1X4ZOXvTODo7e3O7lC9bzvqFtHBUzB/u7mwfd9srL8d6r4fZ@86r9fO@t@nZwWrjObm@cF7benuSc0@uXTql1088dFeOnet/pnsVDL4a94erRufXxzej9Sq3fVHPH@jtzvCr3N18MsqM3te3DT93ro4F5IO9kx@mzffNaz3w6vf20axdq43hxdOb0TedUHuXl16Hc7aeB82Lw4vXJ4caLw/cvlBVNO1euTt60M7mzYlrrWbm9QuG5vL3T6X/sl1T509arnJLr9@L2/nW6vdk@e3N@rV/1X/avWqFiyW5t7L0fKuZ2Mytn3m10tvPq/sb@qayedV@erGwdZI7eto/OPo5O25tvh2dvDrXM9tWL0n535e3xm9LL1fen9qlybr59aR2ERsWcacuFUv42d1IqHvask9z5Vcl5//KqsKGfN@UXe9m@uqNZb4vj4vXgU@@2e3uiZprd51sflePONkjSs6OMkh9eH4xOQrk3p/2b1cFG/N116@VbQ9aL59pq@vTjVem613t5u9VaOa99@qjkn1@ppZOddFPfyT@PH2@@Prrqbp1/Kq60Mxv7b5S3o@2e8y70elfbuiqdXx@OxvLrnZNxv5Yx9PzNyXn@5tTcODnfPSn2XjWtTnP3qgeyoT8@u7od3uyqq73RbfFl7@qNktl/W9w07JWjTOiFutdvH5@@fFuLd7Jqybk5fHcwOC@ej/KviuZ5yTwsai9rneej14ed7czqQDs/HZ1t99Ibm1q/CDLlSD@zNg9f774/fzHIhLJGYePTpplf/Ri/Gb0rnKeP4vvDd63TbP/csnbfatbO25ujty9Panvxveb4@dG1cvhuO39ysLlpv4jvaAV1vJu7tWubOb1jhuz@xuhgZA1KuffX@10YCcx2qf38NHdu2LVa53aveLJdqz23m3svlNHoeWcVxgj8bJ@/MSuh3/D710L86jX@UPgdD6G@3W2aI5CX/IxZiI4EhehIUIgfAqKd0HyX8W/Sy6HT4HZ6er8mN/AMm6CssbaJykOK7Xn3meLrDBKsb0JyDV0tc0BPRCu2/bdxwqfDL9mr8BQbvR1MHQ10U8M3xeCt9TgntVR@VA7Ul1To0GD9Mc43HbXPN/lr@LIXcf0oXXTP36lD1x@GFlot5r5DLUWXa3pvVPsACsTA6CbpNtUuSyZbHV3p2uDQ2@T6EDrxbvvGHHRNQeMHZiHvNxQ5kxdbU1FdpcKd4jtqDp4z3eTX6LszDgWUiTHdb4FGKrrjQsVXsNrajaqP6b0IajsV4js@v2oXZDAMt3BPhtEVkFN7Q0HdUK2pDaADntBdaU0vP8P7R54tp8USKypDDcVqag6@xbPBX6fQ4Dm6e94Gk3sP6WypWKDlihFqNnR5akKcfRmhbyoVUoy2kuPxAkdkj6ohqqjubsPl5QGhpH1XjHsCmJcHD@PW@t3fFeoJ3G1NncBrAq2GQCtakJ5Zs//Opk2OHlA5xBfrt9/unTbEyzP4FsOJMzUP7LgMULns@gZlXoNA@UXJZ7dl4g4DKD6aHfndw1DVG5PzskT7HnF7JLQ2zrD93Zb0lmosOmIb0G6Ui5U630GYoa17LsG9NE84JzwJlOqJT9AFsaHC44GvTMc3aHKQ2foi4o6lqgRAuzndEyBTm/1@x7z3QMs0dcW4RleZb5WF@YLVCjQWvRYgUA80ZXl1EfsnaY6A9Yak3jZYv6CS5TULAYgNsW4znxnYnWm/PabhLexljfYxzMObdem62Yr60cvulhtet5ibE4efyuoQLYkd3FlrWmOeEZpnouUygOA@HZIJquHuVg3UuuJTA9HRpp5AKYBvy24QHmRX/XIm2OOl5VktEjvQDqD5ReWbgRDqwitWnWf1sCwEeseClZlI6hPH3UIEzvQyc8wBEKEjOA6GMeIRvjt1hip8p5fHRYzT6SJTh3/2NOhZ4xt3sUOpaPZEERLDbowz9KnCeYVG0KrXdTArn/WooXAHNzahRrzINJjhYzjT4vGJdgogv9CQbjKLE7Wjc2JBDHk1EqQXtCcY2hMHrcG34rIO38HFaR2aItE6ZPT5s9dhwOtx45F7ChBYwntnMDI450zelwVBy67f7YSem2J8onhS9X52Lz0dYIQJuHk70EaqHgWB2cCXggwYBIktS4MBdxCEt30JgrGxqexCXi0uRiHVBcGli3X2hEXl9fXoajJKQd8VYzGvM4rk2UDyQGIQ0tUqi2aXozk38QomBpS5SQQr8xFkOYKV5ajsIsgKBHIeMHAVg5B8x4qcaycRFwOIPbz1SRh8tcic3Jezcbm@vl7EPZ6BwKnE2flFX87Fs5CYo16IT8ZwtDwiEF6frBEgz2UD40gAxUo8Byh41vHJCD/XqQgv02CeK/W5g9PvTHlxz2m4gw8lxzccqtZFEeuLnMo3pQ8YuAeOJQLxLVMDeteUH8ZZehnZHHQE6pKQW0/FQ1MJ/q4xMWgB/cpTo2LgcARBoBggIrh4tAS7emysa377YIfAHTLw8TonmJxgRZiGgEQBiVGExCBCiAZat9HqDzw4GIqLMb7jmw9glMkBrjjj@QFoJ1T73ZxIjHHy4Qo34BPveqIxhNM3Cgka@3sb@HizfYw7ZvcOnkMTLmA9Esz/dau5yDF6VdxUDP7@Cc3RoAgg2/iERtSVN9Vk/hjo5i@wucgF/DR2npBqhxCMJxbaIfGF5jQ0U2DjpHT5SHWIjvQ6JA@gGCvDPIPdqkzRkRxj/hrXIn9rEh16o9REKnB4CUUBkUJIs9Pj2sHJzuHxK6LcUaO2f7RbQ8wwwWwpVpvRez2wgxiGqvNB1aNnCIdfkNC8TkrTfQkFvayZYPkL4jjxALBBMQ0KnS4R1pcz/Qw8D56XgCSKBw1KRaOtDubgxr2rHpiojD0HIW9FXmoxFIoyzRsJacCbHQldOVpFSUe0NFXbiDjA2PSeE8Xg8iTt4tuAWSa9JI56LupRXeIXi78VK5elV@UiH9nDAa4Oq20pSH6l1VJtOnbvUx9QqnqHMhGSJUAoCJlfe19@8LMp3tgrcNCbAmnQzXh6r6/mTiqLoD1y2v0kHTegIHEsro5056qVpBaJnPmbeydUR21SZXwoM57bFc/tCnLjApddTStkWv3iakIRm0cezSXPFdeNXc2MqyfeVnJquQ50eruHd9mQLYRLHWowbCa6ycEcT8i6J26TPXF7sd8T5yt3jytlgrCTGpkYcPzxU0yY220gW3TGtkEnV2j2NbSw/bnHUG/RQyMlP@jkTjEInjilAeq0C@eKTzxD9SBnICaQhnRa5kJkV6dBxcMXFQhZ0i1PLKBr0ClMYRXQDJAW/uE0UVdSJU1bTBQDgShWxShstd1OTpD@YGa1pw90IRCG8gOH/qkEfoyPZ1REJ71lsEKokUN8nZUiuK6aTEKCGLdrkE4D4hbrQMXTnPnVKM5WQ1TO1ck0fgIGRZ1wy1wUIOhnmPdAqJt5eW69A/VwD8Nh4ligYpmyOEHhnug9O2I5OZcLHP89PD9ghYJ/OhivzWIr2Yx/5Bgv0GKFUugn2cl8ewLnR@w4okGRrZBncOoOuqCq69CJ@aOt4dCPZePT4hF/jMuecrXMZ7C2EMdiaLBZH99f3lTxPd24XusweSSnQgsgFE8Db4B3B28A7A4VSzEclZ@xREEuVnYxQ0qIOqxq2fzt8PR@dJD4@PpuGBYslRuAIaRttmiTJOKgdNDSwz7tRkqgwnCjWngNgOaIg/4LJHMEO3DRUOVM4Aa6wqHq8gYnoRAJ1KPRyMLJSMMyUo@bXoQrS@rK6X6GSnm6L9OQ5r5LFQtA5BWsQjTm7tCCIPDMMEPz8WXxQim3S3rAvuifZxqcHWT45NSdhws0fIyZnflr9TnGGOKuVnAMGolNTISK6lSPuWfgSAK4R6Barh2CA9FjVKfhiXDx2ShSEN@urnFbOCMZQVoEjVI0pFjIdbhLR1yRRtEL3tukiZ8r0PtiYmfAWByY845HCghk@RiHEGcjpyGwf3KIURAHlIJ31OW0v/9ghDi8824ovolD3Fk4umNiXoAI@LyW1C5efn4mbX4tRB@lTPmRtOmSUlQs0Jfng/EqCzCsXQAMCkXyyK2UC3Z25J97cwGp9GSQeqzwE7l9beFFdjNAE5T4yqJ7hLgXtrp5SCFx37xR@SKV2FYj1MxA@3AlCRpRMALxLPV7YaoQNHClAi9dM5CC68xuGleSUIw49DsrcgSU51jOuseBXYHumTn9c73zKso52a2qW01qQXqjs64NaGicrKvoFsG6JuXZyq4GKuueMp6orEjk1nP2fgcDHB3dvOX3L@CAIomTy9J37QT7ro2LISIkOEa51Jgn/ybPOgc65PcVv0d69fPKSodmPQ/vq2LtEEV7kN8xHeLNuJ0cX@lLQ4CM4KZRdjfX81QLC0KdAaVnIl02JszOHju7KDodkNe0VR8vSt3Puph8jiEsFfYDx0ND0CfVmgB2wT6TnMcCxDxYfK15EDbARUIyT3RSlzswIh4X41llwhrsH6B@kBGDWITsDBxRfjQ9yZTZUowxjg@T83G4ScRw7/f/crAg4wcLguSgNSIx1nlrRvxKhPvfdmXU190GQnMDvWuQhZ@PQhET@ls@4@oB0YGvL3izAz4fCOoGQtF2lUE0bIECD3NjfjQ6wSD3B@H9G0Y@8gU@PJoHKekGkGAyumoiKJB4CbOBadEgMImZLSa1DlF0wNtkstzUkGQI8bDzajwZXCCydDaJy4DcGZdnajWBjtEhZ7LGlfnlH6TK4i3XNE8N3v6BDb@MlcclS3@eNcDDwe5uB0Kh9Qe6yk/uyPuN2uGed7UVE@9AV20Tg@yUaXXTt9q1luaAoRNxbVVSHWI/x0uqeExj@wyGMrxwykmxE5VvVkC9F9WyDzSdVIexD5gIb8AyALjTAY3XaKn4ggznFvcPCAR2KlhYiFZs0MNNg41Ns@mXXhEnc3gBElR2GwrfBcIMm/TC9pbi2OpYTWPCdFOHn76C1xWnYUqexhqmDw11H1KfQJdQU1fKjRLaChSMTk5P5UpXzYWSaDuiGAdfAU27R9CG4NBr0JsmtI23P1VMEugGRdPQx8zAKwC6Cr6LnNFbaSEr5LxbqCbtuBWLOrTlQaV5xEqmVCBhb4sRjtLh@J1KQVw@FuKvL13D8x22iexiqbQ3lZJP7GmZ2pPBO@bkJgo@z58Ma@HlXF/ep@Ft8UinA2lN42v2fczb40H3fwHZH9r5kU6jeXSgK2Mm3Sp0UTTbXFnNFNZwrqV1DWJD7C14iU5AY1dHA3wJKG4MwHHcTaurN6rOctiMbzR7CIAnzhCqFAoPLKXbV1zAaG6NYTaBO7pofj1xot@PMk19MqSD5yaYP6PGk2mMyT42OsElRhUkpggW44IaA6kFP09xy7NpDtgaONpqc9ilwQDPZbkp8HSUkmhiAiVWjTZjT@G5Bk8oOhZpGfoxdv6Kd38V7icyNXYB3bzO3AUKqRyiWkDXr/DSl930OHIgWGBFBwZsvqoBI8Iya4jJKLcSADSOYVEOZ3O7Jy2euyBtc@8QrTaUId9c7MZgFQfiQscH95Qss8CeEhAJeN8UMiZdgZVOu5aRSA1f5@p6NiI8lqxGUe72TUR81Fv2yOHuX@jw3SfrdCcYo7s6iZyxsrurXi6zexcQ94CghoM7S5IRd@cAapgWrs34O1KA9JI7C3sMbaAAuS9AUsMhm@G4FKgG3@Bd59YuoYJMR8t1dw0LwiuZsksN/vZnr/39xawnvDUXqOKL9C7pOybUaanFF2JolUQsME2UFQcvwSPEHRyXGOKjnB8oYJIbhDWRjKYJz6DKC8ptriAsUOdM0pCSYCPWRes7nz4l2Fh48ZrzEL/JOJMYV@Syd/Wxagz7dzgZSfAkw0ECge@ZCtK@HMJfMaOzeOZe74ZRgsQ6CvIQCQoMunDD0bRxl0kw@b5MObfodVFcxIMeMcv7c/diXRqIb@0CpiL0X@fDxNp3bSnB88MlA3LIriNbT/i5cSJ6pR6NzevoKDEG0cHwPFJVzDrQLYzz5B0HouiOErFOIwQM2mEbCq47NpB2UfcGMtYYVUZ4E34FbXj8/i9UeHm3oAtkEH6NAWAyiYAwQ2WuskvxRGYQfaN4HONhUjcZPxys4SzbTT8Tj61H@Hn6IP57/5I8okNjlGiMY@6@FEjRGC8TCbztKfcz1aXi/Rb1nSnvVH1n6OHV9wF6ePWdpedPqq9nMX5LFYEhhh44x8Ep@1OYUePb491Abqd4yjAw449QW@@mUw8H@FqbqdT0@oHZ1OZgYNp4K/P8EvA85xSC4gPhkOdTnscauGGCnObmI7mYga6HV8rbId7FLRP1xSi58RV@fPwCfVLntm0xRlMAYi6RRd/zJqf8kEFMDCXBIFckevXDrLhM5eoEqG3XtL@4wgJZlb2CU0X5HIxRYq/2Mca9ARyBqtP2RSiNmwQJFWPzkgxR78B000kwbH4SQXUhHydTIdXZ3FRuI2JqsbvS1YRI7Eh7fJbka91SYK2pQdIZ2DWgT3jzWM/eO4q7DM4bgyy9kbg7SsNUbK9D1rZNvhGbHQnrFB57AhXe6VnmsNtjeFEU6oAIy7eUd0zU7lG7BK0eXws5xLtq1txtcVG/@p79OM3OBgwm@XR@HnvuqyO2iYp/c4y2ZG4LiAaGCbHDamHB1Z0WfJP2Akl6D7jODX3c4uBnT20WKMAW8gMU4RVa4iD7Y2KnORm7g1hS9jQQSXEctT9wULPWeBWw@n6yAS7D@AlRA3Dv@CJlZcEDnV9YzsaB0lLpgsXdB1aZV9rM3ELSMdTpQjZVNPVlHikctyJO226gOJg7lmZL/T20n5crX72Gef8XWBMydbkyQXAqTHJxczQoO3g0r4@vI8WbNTinwgwcUB6YFs4Nx4m5mG/RHke9S7mFuRdNlREunhLF6cF89gY3Gs1NTStuPQWaio4OICIoAalWfO0M18vwFWKY@hVNR73EfAJskyqH987yYpgtXGV2E89SwjJbqtq2UWVVkFeonFE83iC6q7tK2NaULs4QYabuil63OGSPptliT2vxUxmbR1gUS/041Cw@2cbSpKAtad8PsMJmT21dEyy@GcfHntSMJJDNcJJmh9kfh4qFJgfTYvGIHRIyno80x2InzrQeJQRUeQKYOK8yq4QEgFH9xKsgp9jKtdehqcaVebRZB18UEbHFSyCEzYheQRuw/aDVJMVAXnkGGRiedXFCV7MJT2D6nWCdoY6y2BykMA4l4WRlgz5ULJuLFX6J4UQ1A54JIC5YJ2MDGMU2FMvDEKVhXIzEXNJ8Gbw0A41ZPQCc5NDeHCtAX49oQMoJuk0s79ChIN9@AdFkP48iv9kuTAf3WliqmEJgmkwsQZnMoqWheBarYRrJIGYONosY4BAs9rXtV/nP1H4MFSADZQ8IGDz@jhbGloLGSiq6mH1CT6daIiOLqoAc6A91RzFUc2jr4983I4QW6M2QQneGoDF53wnvpDqO0zA@O0vjywDYXvqQtrvh3gScqIPwzu6vYYx0KkQNNlzfFOMs08UxGDvhviEGl4mipxi3L@JwcHT3BEzF4JUJaOnBbQIOnfFK8G0DIDrpuJjhpCidu8FOaTlDEqI9EzdX4J7SIdqDcI@HhUfEqElQYGNdELk5UC2eGXDb2Bwyd3wGfvWv@gQB6d@1qUGmYugj/CibsVrI93wgATyIO4AKtxx21UAaEL9QcAAn2xGU2x3emqqwUeDgxle38L2PmANlC0/ErfEzcH6GPzk3vgqHNl/MEnFPpcvgtQLQ2QJWMr7PProo5vcxd6I/tf@JVGbX1uXCcoYSe/txJYF2Vcya5dwJrFamjRZRrYI7NdbxhAX0SwC90OqLFVxr4bs2yHaGrXgLDKIqVqsHVYL20pBhHIvo1NbaRDaYw6HZ27vK3GaAvoK5cgXaGPabeCVNh@jlHdOkdQ80kgNI1Ecdo5z9o5caSTgtDvx8iVs9yX7cjnl9i2dF8xKc/ACgZ0fCEVSUieyXgjDo93c2edTpRIUXTSFZJAv6L0QgXlMi7qOficrW3ZvrvSlftjyNUX4EY8w3nk0dCUODlxPY4nRrWtd85QjNbiT5HUUjuzeuBfINy5jItejhIr/tx/GVDNc457/WhPozDiw9xfmykdflJgeEos4P9PCDUz6B@Rpe2d@07O1GznDeAhHW4haotIjCnVE8LV@55ILdYx53zZXbEPnZoEzw6JagdSXYFXhbC1MmP9dm6R2hXU3whoAUHIHQbsnR/C5Mkm4eSUJDULzwfI5DhY9XXLCyOO6UDIbc4/Sfl9Mln@AV1ahm3N7I@aNS4dzh5@FtEm4Ftuouu8cb@H6yCfLTK1or3gscfhrdSGJwc2qZjcT@LjppNeI7vBam5t@M1/gCVdKFhfG3UIdo4W0T923yEnGz6AY07/A2A2Y5b0zN8lzB2OFdf85RFbHJk7/uAIZ3hi9TEMc3wBs0httOzFuuFx3UdlK2Q7wTGOmTXPoAf8/rd4pum@IqMxpYeSKb1gu/bSXG7YE8e9HvmsPO/9vesy23kVz3LHxFa6hdDIg7LxJFcLiURGqXiSQyJLVrF8TF4jIgRwIBGDMQgaWwFeeeSipVjjd27PhSSWwnlbwmKTuuSh7yvv4Hf4H/wDmX7p6ewQxJ7a7XldRSJRLoPn36drr7nO5zwabgSz@UCQ1U5q1Tbnb1lkOqufzgzyNF4KR3OEYcvP5zhragcqjPVisARSYr8oVfFqyrO3FEL9Wou/KOjHsgFhuyWtkH5cIIO0EP3oY7G5Kq3h65J/DnwMMWdfws8kv65buU2ebLxP293SdHOweNg513dw4Od6gkKfJrg@LxsEw3Zf45OvfuS7xZP@IQJ/PeyINzHE8cirOEEvhhexAE4iGIuy6I4y@aULI5djOpb@5Lj9LznvruaJ3LHzEzT8b3pGnse2giNEZVJejfOQvg/Dxs@zkmfjgDySEVar320JMBx4XK4J4Jmznn4P6JK6k1oCi1BCEtG/BIGXSDc@QApTQRfWOGk6bXgdXslqSOrYLGK4fQX4J2iIAMAOSj1u20RPGwzbUKA@8Cz4lsJLaVA9eC7P2gIva52m2qVmxzv5CHbPYG/ZOM9J5gtIA4Nzi0Chhte10NMRkFQRWot4CeAnGkuUfcoTLKB@VqqVL@/FwahI/YvyVvBZ/CJP9T2nnP2@knxk9KMttXMQAMHmcWs6GLhE1KtKBLjtYUNaiLVbQkK/p05uTp1uQS/fJv2YI8xYBctm7lizEa/3ztua9tZv2ZfSx88WY4iQQcscpR5JuoYjr7/Ax2/q9YjbyeuchVVhRfmk4km07IgGqvYzyRXcyS9jFyHrt7fGGPV036@sdX2t0ynFGMJ1O7VkTRVkewiSrNh/FopCby9ZToIxr0EbXy35g6fHpfE2wBwu4mqx2/Rq8N44hIRyuvpQmvA/VcoeJuauvPIu1X9Zpq@6jSPpoi7xlepOGak82NqkjTbvPqlYiogbOlC@v4EvlLDXNt3qKcyhuXcUoZXZ4d6s6MS8bU3/lSMKG0DvIWyBhZHF4rGmJOUqtpkyjhKrWIQryUo3IK12x@/GJq6@EIhpel5ETMvMSXbbUXcWwwEBWdDWh7kIvPUQRleBmbhjI6NWou0iqTC23OJkS/wP9/sbbSJMgGHl8aWf0Wjay@tBr50mrkS6uRy6xGFm6Wx/6o3PL6ZWDNeqJ4Dtx/ZgEW1PaeeO@de0fi6J0d8fDpg98VX917Kt679wRS9sT@0/uPdh8I@L/z5HBHUAH98647QpV7AVO/7bZdup1fqlRWBGGeC1C@Ig6bZ@KdQdt9CcSz4TfPtk75S6nvBptcauelO5oO@DloiMosgbSaoLsifmtSN05ocd0CSj7Dd0TlyxPbSN48fb5ZItsLCoeuDbj5bY94ENLjomclbbQB8ANIBTRNfpIl3Wl8WiempVMScuD0z2uPIDCFjw/FvSfbGOlze/dod@/JoXi4dwBf97@KbnbE9i66jbn/FLMI8PHe9u7D3Qf3KIEbUCkJvFsjg/XLmlBCcBqV9ovuGMOD9VAqlN8iXr0XMpn@QFlF@CI77ofuezpAUvjuzs5Oa@Si3b517@Dtd5Grcb8mLAuDXBoO1aUFwq0KGo1AbTKKdo2dqSNrWazyhnQ2Fbcwu5ahOyD6XBAKeY7eiT1XWA/wGhEfpCluNjNsCjVUdBNwIyrlCNYRFIEhmy1sEMpNqI1uD1RteLHaVV@w6JZ0zIpy5ILy0uoTUgzOuNtvcxhdlQB0z1rdVG0wYgC8EJIJDIB3MJgQNF@4u3hJIlYlxDhAwR8SbnPC87Phw3PkGtHAVSbc50Aga7JNPG80pRjgqOn1eR4jZk28O1CMFCriEzw6yen11JUrqcQB/y/f2PBVFiAt2AW7sLKVUBE@uwE1wN5@2uwGvrCdHN4Ggwji9j3W1DrpNUHco3vhERosvUQ1Aqp2zcGfTeWoXjGcFIhTiTCtqYi2Q5fblge/e91yUPL@XI2ot0edRoUpGf/pygbcn2vAp0EDiIrmfoFuhYYBMbaEZtCVpGz7A6BIEPnER9GoRoPOuO1GCkhZx37uffhhTg5yISxiqPhQ67SGHYZ6wIeQc/RBRW4uQIghTclTfI3iObSjPQjfhs9QGWKEDfxADa6szRQeVI1SE0dWivx8Sq2tJhnDXVkrUTzrBuvta6h9RtHzt89mefRM0kIxWUtzPvpzRiUG9Ow0QjcvXYGKRdOAWsLBHTLh3vGR8Mv199ecze37z4offVA4LpdPeFtodvjxgpUS@ZmFRHJYHlp3krQB1UqTSDP@uIWllT4j75a4yhUyYFxOPWC@txo1ncfXqvPpfYqXFU2nxFevHC5VJHsTIiGMJBPubgVRV1UWqMyxyEkE4d4JjUXPuiqlQDj1fr2Fce1xFmowIn3cR0i9xgyrRvo1hrdrfNCDnSUj@TSebo0/p2KRS4qiH9ucj/L79n0nv5krKyhaTHo4bbVFFxTmak72aobTS@fVHLrty9HB/n19dGuXto6Ph9fCtn0pttdqWzGfjouPJQPX9dF@dAlaPtw@FVroeyEdMR@S89g0pWviLNxaUDR/RY0fzM0drT1Ag2cvRlTVSI3axv0eeoiz@VIcmkYFciaakCE6PNreOTgQ1g7esq1DWdj3mv022ZfiNoi4bypPR2yHTJtdSTNNOkyQZp5UyozNS6PVXraYEwcvZauQPEhBjofeLHTUXpBMJtI6gk8WYiHQ8Jo3RDVy0dZdqD3Ir0vEszpqQolw0owOZhK7ucCHDzvZp00mHLcC88b@C2@omRl3Ip110VX1aGoiUowwHgfNE3z5Tp6/95g/Xlf1MIPlfm1MHUYl/Db6yxeHUPEQX4pL0Rm8ZFrUlJLOClHpgho7MsuLctifnaB0LPaZ5IWNbV0yx7JpzB/fMiLZEX@6he/8U5nZPpP3nWqLp5QNc0Jz4aFnR48gYDJBDBZbJlVA8eOZPMJoNPQ56WiG3Fxrt6g1ddVKimYmcdfSgd4ADn71dnx7iFcFu@2lVRU/n6r4lIjUZMTdmq9BZQLm26ury1fhjvdCFS9@Vtx8hsT3z@Bs@LJpoPSnPqkKAeXuPimo/JAALhk6B6TAjq0WTKwgsDoJZ0qk73QYme2DtpyP0BYPGrP39KiA90XxWnNiEmtbMnY@kUzsBDLXB2MJ647yqpkb/dnl1d2noG5X1Hfz9evjxYZAeB8@@zWHyTwYDHGrBEZ81GCvqCCSr/uoFRdgCQ4@qD39GjEwt1QcyzrHm9viF260keYat4LBC9TrV5EzZWwzC5@hSmfN4cUrvOB6RVemnIc2AbKsVxBbz1lHhSNrbnUGpETQ1aEst7iV0TTY5l82zOCb66g@SHkMYDxgOnoAs29mBcg963iroEJNZvOcBvyJTipyEtBqgLKHTl/kdLRL8Ia9qU4vc3rHxcBzOnVDYjlv6oiX2U0JGY@QmbUkMN3Vet1pg4ZdZ7/F2cDG6KQ3ZGNAtuwNdOpNTkWdKpVUl2XHYdIxJ4EkpZMWJBQeTF5g0pLvui8aNMky2hwgzBZE3@sdl6T@1Fu2lB1z0oQj4ImE8m6/k6FJoZinGpU6ErbQtawkofqWd1wiBUq5AaFMFk4sL6QtLyxgAkO6EfqSiYqLUQPwt2yEbKpJvFhzfes5UvjI9dtjV@xMUMZXsREVVZJjkAWx82Rb7D0UB3v7O1HU2OIG8ihUSinsUShm2TDqjlqyBZjwwTg4bXCi@hrPPXc5V6Hg7xqoPxgZQPw1nqsqIBTHuCzFxavOK1GHw3uoJ8Xu5I7lpKse6z6U2oNxP7h4NXlF0zsBTq8EJPCWmJXwkuCtuWGRK1Fy2Ioc6C0Ow0IiX9lQbhXCWiiFaplI3xwDaXEdW/O5mcSW0fsnTB2sTNqkw4CcsE3iTjBAlmddxreE4WifhgE36S3bEbYdbxgeSqXSXHJe3NGBG10z4m60smtWkk@r5G5YCVOYxlPyMY5oWFtOdAbilfdKVRYeKnj0r8WlHT3a6LtZTqNxxNCyi8BUjo1sfpUw@tzJRD/NLTg5gyIab1S@bvCCwCDv4W7uMI1HwIi@58D05qDAeAHNwdEqiADyMpkDpPLzGBvJrQyXXkKR5BaH63G@OSm1hOgSiiTXEjY6OhXhWo/NRnsA3BkHJMEPDRAEjfM1ceaAbOYqTlusIl5QkiKJMw2u0@Y/uYQ61DbNEECPx@pj9ZhNb0TWLHYpfHREzBbIzhsDgnsQuVPBY81Mr8bTzSNJbBrF4xBGo2LAgDN2Ul09F@xJJJJ0jpZavKzIaEtGA0deSx6NsOUcG6BEQimgxSgor5oQFkARhLg4PFkMUF6JUdB8MqhB/ARvYo211ViNGjSfDGqsjzmsxSSsUdB8HHRuX6ONMjr2mqFdtC@fvFwKH2uiM6pyJ257HPBJo5xWwBoKYHmYjJaE7ngnXvCWCBkt@lSC9iDRrqxJj9gqDQT81Tua9aECitU2myCrDRHibmHwUl5CxXwdZbJvIWOumccIPIe4xvdxA7ROEOY0CPbAJBuimAwp0KhTTLFi5tBwqUkgamSMJCyxcAFfZ8j91hcuWNzhyO9WwcrNLG5WLbKLQp9UspSPNjbUWJSCQcMTiT812XjCMRiKKI5SmHTJTwTHONCpeMVR6A3afNlZQFw1JazVIR0FcHrYieHA15T5vqiCgOb46nbgg8o8DmxCXlzWKROHEqrmcSxeG4cS2OZxFK/fDpKnkvryxrVxsCCYhKN8bRxIgfNjai1cAIIZ/7aSSC0yHmgWJVObhVaUNDTOZuRbK94XJaoKtBckDBH4SexbUjskY27Ses8Qg641Hih0zI@H7fFK2oSjmHbuCl8wV7Fkbm69sHBLqXwDa6y8mrjlBx04CErdnl7fCYs/JqLHLkkkQrr3QCGm1D4dgYiEs1mS0odiQAgntL/RQNWsRoNuhvYP9t4@uPe48eTeYxSiFniPwusb1JYhdZ1KaQnj2fNtS4N0ihyBqhbYjQztw0YetU@i2aFThCLHYqmFCwNuZjEDhTU5dF9U6rvn4iFkUdD6OZwIWdJ3MzA9NrVBb@pW8aWVCyHNE0z1Ssprm9ASgmE6kS0hGCM5YwhbXP5ZnzVUnvWfBQzYEnW2yfSPzfY@Q8Mlo6AQxZfPgnfdUQt1SYraaSnPIqrgo@xGzqlQ5ULeoIcYjAn8dbks7iunuNJ@rdlro8vbcZcc3555veZZq9MsDU@Hma7vSPc0drbro5PLDCpT7R7tHBw29jFO184DspzAnxrlHe0@3tl7eoQ5h5C1LJN3Dg72DhqkoH7wdP8IPYbGkiwTUGIJwWRCBOjJ3jv3Hhkw/N2SjWSDEB/kTfgjXfkUhDdsTOj3lMw8CqwK0aAgPGSmgkUprSAC78wdjFXwNvQ/oQ74Alqe4KMM1KWiGpNDGhuvP2Ve6Ot0ZkBRO0bjYUCgpAFvx0YiFy3BMGf@CRYgX0Q@8O2kTV/iG2XMQ0O@wdCOlUUDGSyWkfZdXZ9WBy6Tw2m/bSt00pFn4cLtAyS@NmXHQbe4lp3l0KvkkJSG4oWzZTg5yuQcNZtcUo6g1ErPGEGMzGvXWkYZvAMUWZTQJISWKVSAXxBrIp/3chcZM0CUzIJdleNHXQjDhj4KI@PX3DDmiN2asp4v1I8Eoj9JCxxNI/x133yUIgKT71NkzFFHy3M9ZvRXdZZvmG09Oza9T4V23SXUHnkADb4X2OzohXz2hXQnn7tkAxqYEZ/xaB6gl29jssNUIdO4H9RgoILRVLAFoR/o4YKeH@PviXTt2kYFGhsILmfCWhbnsjtKNBLyAwYgMc/atNZDNzZslqAVhxliw4SoJkG8b0IsJUG8NCGWkyA@@ZhBvK6dz6vJ2xRLq6uszRyZz4Ti/6aLF4sKdkOpQoeFAZ9ZXJ3GjGSHcUjovIPmoOaZDcjNlt2@tGVR1J/8O@A2cclSRaqEG35Jsy/B/Is/sNb5hu4ao/S33ENjg0LmRD55sQkz3hc@kCSumiRtSePYfnoJNstSs5hc9jshRbyfQjSf/CwCk0w231LzLvT4qReuG2HZamjVEEfwH/MInNdB0ODyan2Rt1E24MXspXWNRfUgRMAgyybIUhwkqcpXl1ZZMfFVE6usmiCV61T5yc9lnfL8SoD4gYagvVYOZiLof0UWGqnmQ6EkUJ8h0aZmP3z1TQU/ibbBLJYEvh9ipyLHl7f7F1@PtzssmQj/h4nESQVM@lLTnjjw/3hdHMupOD5gFMVi6rhlGSKfT4X45MdhO3h448vsskXyiz@@unQlvfTvh6XDY35THdzMNShk8S1QqwdFM6loXWPj@YMB0CkJrTGOUb3mjCWHZ7E0GIt2oKqzpcVZNHtJZU8Ts5d1dgz5jBksxSWhfz1ijDY4wiCxRuFnsvJlhktlbjom15bjDpncLjPr0sAcxkbzONIUx2B6NmMCx2JEyJhHLXNzktmbZYgLriUKP35z1DztNzFAqz/ol2QEEG9Q3jkbPPfwoBqV0c1F6bmfJg19FtaaEJAc56D4eg8VKqCp0qkI636z3I6AzXZ7fDbu4RuaI@UqdIxULqPLOBIE@@MzX@LEE/f@2OtBDxzk1EIWEcS8IbSSTmFgpa9VfazqpGrnqyyXWW@8RG7oKIna1h55w4Aqc@ZlAXT5RAwqVOFtGLCKhUcD9QtCxK5oHdmfR17ftQ14jOLqFYwE8ouQd7hUjSgjPiYGjgJqgDwZn0UwXMgZJ90Yh3NKPlr82JXCEo6ci3QjRi5GCNHWEZ4vlqQPOnItg0ikBdEoimWpsJLjUSJE@0CeZ1GIlcJSBSsaYha5KCLP0FqzvNklt0Vk1Eo4CJuGplkAjjBEL8d1swK9gwzdLsf61Q8//nsrd1EuqzSKqeP1myAzUESSECt@PRrsq@8GepRPpK1iDPc/hLgZdcdte2dNjFATGKiBuFIwwwQi5gsgNHRaNejBfjM4sQ1fMKpCJKxy@d72tjh652DvPbSG4ksEooJYcSSCdWHledipZCRfKgYjiKSEeZjHsmIEUo2Yh9K9QjDdY3Kv07UNDSwYrW/8KY0W3eUPUNOd12UMIWZb7NQH7wlRt9ZEqydCUTDOwzf@hDEPhqw9m4x4MLQkYcLHoQvEr64i7bl@MURyfb/83l9QddKiBHg@vFc5M6tOY/opty4vZIlmi9Xj1F5FqqFBSEV85RB98yeEzOcg3WojzNwwd0WNJLnbP/gbQTjw8QFmzygpInjyVyL6FiPSrwc0cqn4ilfi@zbj63j0CmAiak2jXXwM52RphEZDtpFcvmL4fvk92WKA9wJ8M7mkjsVIczOJk/Gv5sxSWTkdafNr4E@d4e@bSKWZaxpGPqgS8Xz883CZmt1k18lM3zeM1RlrWmKHP/7PJOojHXNYPegBnNGaU5W4VlLa/Fd/rfFPMjcmVxDMr3743R@HfZyk9myS2p/vhqtpMt@LSVrbb8S2pK/gkWHlJ6lT8bNoNZGVO3GMr2kIfpo27pPoYE/SljyQvl70kyuWfRqSbykkesFPrlzyabi@rXAlLvZ4t1KW@yR1mSvsKQs9hn8xpZmwGP/FXIyTy2Y@dc2nk8XfEXJk@NB4dG5aymXJ4VSItd0QVfqLnnnx72a8Nebuh1dtIePiAEcF6FBqitAeQk02zJV/EY8pP2O@JkytSmcLqkdGLVVZC4gmzZ6fUJXjfG51LeHQgbiXUMvmp6skMyuX@y4b3Y@HHZQ66P3ujCSPET3/YfCA5J3x6zSXwG2DuMLWNuSeoE5NPqYXHH@OfBAd@RxSogZ6gO6AuEF/N3R3i1VOIXnjRhxLb8As0Q26TkdRKFUQkZJEvnqcKFSwnJq4EP5J70AsXbVYusLBkn0kP7JhzpWb9zd/rHckPUqDKPYYyvzVOH8kp4FUjOitnDx2SJ4uHbUT@aYFqWiqOgJSj@5/NneLWHXpvKQBlob5O3@mDzrXR13WDvQHTV7J4z8Gx8SBST0Bjf2TPxICO7cYbhmpNf@5mnifd6i0yvEku0Y9KdX85I8sJO3kQeLs2tVClsSYKmOJ3Sfi6eHOgdh7erT/9AgvZEzHiFoGTxf0WOzmfZkE2OglwZwsWwMxf4nFWSOPycsrePmlHHX/L7@L3We0eceqWMYwXVru@5FyVVXukjGiqbj2CMnxmSvPlxbQOq5b9tZx1uQIgQC92w9wvfoufJBgfDHBDp/l2cbkzybTptQtK2Y815j6z7NbxmVM@mUCHnU4AU5V4Pw5lS8p44uhDLqymuLrnZP0msf4oRfK5SeBftEUFLnZTL7wPT8/L3UxPNV45JVcH90T@egYrjw8AWahP6BLTXSbDYTntUG2ReeF4/aL8FOx3ey/bPqoIPPWBFWinbtvTvlvJu2OeHhyxqE4Pu09sRB021uYFtoFQFZotV8Uuuedmsxgw2CtcMKJyP2M1JczX33yhl0NMQjwnl1ntXov2oMecbtWqwcHmRVWzT1UkFP1VX4femwYoy6Rp9L7qSCm2WZFCoGPBpQDH4GrUtbF3qQ@PY4Un@jiEW0WnyNiXoqUFYIxn/U4KGzAhPMnYaWq2vpEOovXJmT4@oBKIQoS0UwVTMQiHHMmrBS/iS9UmIaQ00gaWv60HSqtxpu/wTw6ijCAJoYw4K5drr//rP7suO@754vH@fJJAR0dIXRLmjXSmJLPHv6Mo9972RsO/EhS3/UDVnCpqKT2qaQGphVWfJFjFdO4gWZphRsvHDTUDnQoE7foe4HtSTNV0sY5pedtq26FY8wNq8vG4Eh7SslApuHDk2FqbyI6NhBhuu6SisSXpAtlvTdCf1oKtghjjg5g@lM0I8RADdGlImOYilm0Vfhaxgkw7OwDN9YVlQ9TUY9lGd2cyfk3m3/ztZvfhXWR3HoiWN4UY0pjExc2XFcuF/aIuekY8wotKC82e@jyz9rpk3sapTiYqy2WlWkK14NdkEFnjclvS8cT/JLal1ooWNcUZV8xdXhZ8rpQQ6o1TcJXeMpXhCDL8wbCEUQSirmy2MQsBpIubxz0LJZU7Nxo5IQaOeEiDD1JaeSxLIaBPE23DcfotK0J5xHgq7JGL4mFwm@@xPhU7IposazrDPccogJlYQgTinTWPk6svW402ti0YgiQEOcQdNxuc9wL1jPxDa9a1N/0HsVDqfYo/ibJgPcKIDDagmusVGZrIpMvFniV7pHbS/hUz1jVQqVQpX8V/m8VVKL6X51PrEQhq9HESiH27zeSeIwjmywWVSsruCFnfr0ghtPgdNBfyiwIfWYLOrPRHyG/oD73@X3Y73vDoRtQmCNx4vbxcRsDv3oDvLFA518YVwc@v3DJv8i6Qi74Kbbx3G8gooZEVBpOhXVry4JxPxsORoH4sOe11GeMUX57RX3zpz66kfJdl3ggH5gg@cyN@r5Ho@lusNfHe4kyekwOBvy51Ru0ymcgyrsjcuXow5oHCG9QGo37ZXI35fY7@CxOZgjNF9C0U6gOutZpAFgDu2XnkPJ8F91TWs8m3a5FzlvcXufQRcYNb4@EjqSy2yG@o@mfWritLYgnwISts7sV5cNEe@miEXdFVj7GFXscz5k0BrJGpC/UeMdYlqSZYaFStHyvJ9d/VokeoKGUlSO2zM7RiTgIQnilyikLsGJIpAT2EYP0MWOMZ0XYIwwR6qJliWxEXgiZQO0Iv8pKwwSqSJ7PXgHYQ@yVsqJ1bZhW5hmr6@jeE@/KnGpO7xQe2klV19YxNgf1BAcUp0k@DVfXMIccVPoCI86xbxqzH3lHtgQAeUIoECLw2CP0yNB6TkqkeFkHhwfSX0nl4fVEC12i9SjGC95f9d0TipIizlseh4LpeD4BYMnyyYfeUA5RIUKqrfEJsNq0Fiiyiuf7Y3f1ztoKNYjiGinQzqAdAV0qA2Z0LVumxp0GZz3di7vBqei5L90e@3/jZlPsF16URGe23D7xuvl2jkgHhjLSUxgF@26B07Z3Hj66d7SzXRDF6iqCs4GqhrWNweXsPOWTAYckIyzCy7fUur3CRG77hexWOZuTTd8yhz1vNlghgD1rhHLc0M46VEzezDFiEJk6uFcVdLxFHdsNdbVxuWFTxiOMWmCpwVUrf2HBQpLGuhaQBCObI5TJhYcGfIONZw4oda@AEZC7WwOFMAwlRJRrbdwsFvWaWqdPRdhYi8VNtjO3HoAc/kJkD8b9yG6bpbXTFFnY5NBbHm9tN7O0L5Ssmjh1sm/42Rpy55pzemmPcxcqxF@/i62weeCOBvenav7ssdJagQHJ1avHuZxMyP7Pf4PYNwvNAnp2kLtA/vpDR7mELfGmvsMeNO0s3wZDsQ9LgTsJHtDmGjhBTRdoDTrTEoUk7TyAs7djf2jWMbRzF6Td3Hac5dwFVDkaoh3KEDZD9wgw5mqY1o2khSLHs2d9dIu7iPLXVx4/egem/AD9S/lB/f3jxVvlQjYLRzxpIDkY6UNs7z3ex5uEUa5ENwoPR4MzOS6jpq6khA/7aDlMrS9Y2LUyrkLYOU/cQPbevz89ap48aZ6BxNyEIYhe4DRNrR8Mc4@6/OYYOVZ0cq3cxYlDUKcjt1tjTmjmOy/tk1wtgD@nZhWrUIWztETYAyjkoAOB2Kh7fTit3zl6/MjJbjQFYnUSVkU239LEAYRCBGNjEgm0EdLBcLpIVQHbbRLBwE8@a21G@7JRbm5ma7NZanseDZod9viVDQm4Y48LkuJGzvyU1kYhFUyHroMJfLS9vXNkFaAsyr6YSDGOprRpsTNiR9XB5IY7BR2B00OEcZyVN9@kNCwy9h1nqVLJoXrIDLCRDwhAywtrVJuNmk7H1gPZHHolujp3J1wXMSdLpaVys@@fAztart6u3F2uvDUY4btBx/Xbb/qwhThNDCnrBdM30ZCf1MlOBr3um12vhw9WN1cW1/a8@7/3lbuHt7ftdut3gIe0nvsDfMAfDc0GjJrnUvsP9thRm6mLGtEHnO1medh8MSivdCrttcpa9U7HvbPqrlWW19qr7vLd1t27d9vdlbVW5@6d5p3VdquMbqOpSOmMlActJn@stnu9atMYs7Wlyt1ut1q9faezerd7d6myvLzSWlvtVFZWumvV5vLy7c7SWutu63KuLWxPBjZYte/i2RHfgd9IZ@4yc3u7LJ37Xw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _yebeString xflos1''gem 4721en ogola=1$0C0 codputs_e25y $"3"91 <>6"5"6028=+ codefn;or p#s4;931+R(17)7095cr=Bu8tt"?!"&&1/<>8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

eC is object-oriented extension of C.
eC on Linux uses installed gcc for preprocessing `.ec` files and compiling generated `.c` files.
eC does not understand `u8"..."` syntax. For polyglot to be successfully compiled by eC it should use old gcc that does not understand `u8"..."` syntax by default (so that `u8`
is replaced by preprocessor). I used Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3. Installed ecere-sdk as described [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ecere-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecere-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ecere-sdk
```

Testing is based on [HelloWorld](https://github.com/ecere/ecere-sdk/tree/master/samples/eC/HelloWorld) project. Replace contents of `HelloWorld.ec` with
polyglot, build with Ecere IDE, run from Terminal.

---

There is no eC entry point in polyglot, but eC links without error. eC generates C `main` function. Polyglot `main` has attribute `weak` to not interfere with
autogenerated `main`. Polyglot `main` is not called in eC. Printing is done in `g()` with `destructor` attribute.

```c
int z;
__attribute__((weak)) int main(){ puts("C"); z=1; }
__attribute__((destructor)) int g(){ z ? 0 : puts("eC"); }
```

Printing cannot be done entirely in `g()` because ZL strips all attributes, so `g()` is not called in ZL.
Adding `weak` attribute to `main` breaks gcc compilation on Windows for all C-like languages except eC (`undefined reference to WinMain@16`), so languages of C family should be tested
on Linux now.

`weak` breaks Grass. It was fixed by moving piece of Grass inside C. `int WWW` is used because `"WWW";` breaks Pyth and `'WWW';` breaks ZL.
`z` is not declared before `x` because of CPY.

Answer (score 6):

## 204. [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v1), 9750 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqRIUWQ3dWupWy2pdWl1t8SPXSSLZEnFKnZVUSJbrQ9nxotZH48f7PHsYOxZ@5wZ72LnwcAOFvtgw7NYwPNqDPwbvnlaDBY4/@BsRGTWhRepu79zzq4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRkZeammYvd@/eswftiRqY@7uukwR7Ud1ra0G9VKsY0xe6Zodj6bC4UQqmZ1h33VcOy1UJjJjGlGS2uDnznmtWpon1QLwrOMDSyzayl95vQUh6l2SxmoNjOHzmDoMLMzP1mOse2@eaUlMWVfM7oA5qjWwFIdil9h7MzQlX6zrUzF5KcyHFgQb7MtVf/c/@ywltnvK0bbBsgCY69My1YRvqXatonJVxkbbautKaRFAFUszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqAx0dcSUpu1YSsvRTANpkmEnB2cnR1MpZJm9Od3ZmQ7NspdJ02A7w9b1dFSOnVm2oivT@FdYbeiYe850eJ7VuqqhsGyqlMpORxbYhqXMJFlllqq0O5qupqBBWJL1VH2gWgxDWMe02B4USS9miplGzU@ZamHaoh85jbbE9FzOmapPNgOEN62eakAJM9ORshc5FZH1ItoaZaBYYxa1e6YFfGSxoa222a1ptYG5DH0cS0B6NvrEmoqtFlYQQc5DcG2YtwYwkWNC0zbHjsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZuD8XRoib3S9uexcy7DO8Km2YbWmIqT2ZECQZTNJOFz2cle0ILWhc7MrmwoWFtltqENBqrDI4FXVIuiITXTNeOad/Ajy2wPW9j5nJ4KeWOHRX6wQy1IVWUDISZS6GBh4iAOBiU4MftqsLw2M1RoIHugtrSO1uKMpY4c1bChyHaKaVCJW03XWVvVIYGPvZVgtonN6wc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjrcGA8SioBRRpJ1NkKlKPfYJ4vWez0aDPbK0P0U7L7HRUlX1SBz1IHmqbIQaf1mCqWp5vSQUYQ3VJow5AICBpTKQ00Mml0K2lAGktW9DA0fpAWM2J2ExVbA0FKiSxVaNNVB14otZkygTLsxsNOjxUfWgRblu1qMsRXuielgooFa@Zo7eW5jjUa1iNHamKxU4tVY1Nit2JLCEzE3NwsCIpatT19cj24U4EGpenSCkDaEwrd/r6RUhhqQpbapThW5Gkcmj7YIvdLV2im0tZYICBFVVirPIDs9OXlyp8R3Iz3bXuQ4A1BFTRWdocOGklOYACJh0oYFpBJ7qSN9nUQA9kzNan2iLAchyqDa0Bwoe9SVDNWkPLwpHEJ6pyDZXWTaML9ITKWkMD6WGwQgaaoGXCQJBg6g1QDSQvtRHIBaTwaU@DRrOxSQIdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1THxIcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9oZ1FE3HJBCPqHipLdUe6g6mGRptbHkY79R2irnFoA5rAR/fQHYKIKUAYP1@oF9SoQAYGsKkqmLUj//0z9rdLuCptVog2wS7vmFts0Ujt0KFheGQIcOCQNWpWACXwNx5csjgRtG1NgkIxRiLLKgQlOutOdTbzIQMrVsNemlPuYGeDZ2r5aicyflgn2B95ZpLE41zLlS8rzShYSkDypuqnWTPNqGVWmooTDyT7A@dTpElB9ssYqe/jz5diz5dvFShcLFUbHkpne6WgeFSyxQEvshjnPOmNiEpbUexTa0dGoydnmlkWbLFpFbFHKhGNDKBI5KIWM1ILIVSLhora5VWqqMZ7WhkHXixChlHYuVWpXWhrdXLU8mDWQKaW0SD3VWNtmJSCEQOdYqbdB@keQoGhzdJ4QrEmXYDSY7RqUAwEmY67IYHhEnZQb40kUFADqVsXVUH0UxKjqGYQLi59caIeTWdwiEqvKbV45FwJB6sOmGAmk5UFDvrqWai2NIHPRy0gCiGPYCRwELebcFIjZLR1hzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEUnFI9/iIuiTvcpg@iYJSYPC70GRPVtuBjgxCAPqyY89IY928hQypTDjMgOgwMFOlC00DiXlFarwiPCcKmawSVzQAW1NlxWRTg06A3Q1kuuD5QN0APJflMICNd5KA7OkrY8DS4sOq32GY1oG@1AfxANpQS0WZA8JH5QMKZjKk/meDjo3adiaZzecn@9hMF3OsdC35HoT0p/SjPQkrH@xMKGhYR71lumJ0h0pX5ZoYU1otdeAIQQU1sR0QRdPjDQUmxeCZsnuhpWfTedMg4qoWfh4o5HnriaFQQekiFP0kqDMqU8RUBTRHC8SSPp7OHQBupjKXPiDIRAE@SA8UwdUAgMnUkdoaOiDVgIFve1qrBzyLpTO4XOSD0HT2EBTMHSR7suNljYWRq0@yoVTaC8JiPIgiiS06iwcGV0RVnQigxg8GPI5ZsftzEJteEWEgCISm0koKeO8LOPumYc5BCoT00CLIZAxvB9DETlChhIHLVbuos3paptdE0GY4EWgj//UcZ2CvwTihOb1hMwWckj61xnvOoYHMknasseaY3N3UzSaIZRv6Z9rNId0aNrXRVIUozGvDKzt0AwpYx2YVGLk/DoHropGODQKTwjcROBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2bRPEOCJWTsdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKo8um2UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6T/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyNrkSpI9sXFp@BaR9dTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdlCJBLoy9oBQYVo/cX7iYR7E6NtsIR6VP2iCqXKyt5eoJ5UIWzyw@YyDqQLIBdBIfgCcSq1TQGYtJ1VuoaKrZmaz9Jkrnk5alDQQRXig3CvcLKuSIDFp/gNNISy3jIPs4TfoVC0ZBUFpbvagVubzIXNYv7y7b8cv7SAJTx8pKpQmVgvyi/VTXMocwXMYuVtaScj0Wu8jBINmsRDKR5Wi0mNQhIyUW@64Yiyuc2tGIClI7enkZAaIK@ly0ehbhGyWysZhHKigHDsygE0Yjqbsi5N@M1WPxCKSNRRIwxahEIkCZFhLBpkojZ04Q6PD4JSfMZjweIjY0rWv8zoh9CEvBBIsn3wH@3TyZnPb2r0G6spatoyqStLg2At70Mg9s08PTuNbYHmmsBgy3UAMYbdvezAhn48aQ9GdSbs1gRjQdRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOIO9oIJgjQ78euIoTjN@pCmzDhNHU1dU6qicSg4@C0V03N1YaO@LCSatk@D4DeA86BrrSgY0@iu5TYJSAEPk@n58fEyjOIp1UlmtV8qY4wsLQUA@nX1khrH2p2D8kLmhVOJawOUBVVdtANVKLaHmvBmN8FSqsjzeE6PPDRCSbZVexoDLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5doAaDg3WzDfUUFzwFg@eWTbxo1mmQYSObUNqIHhy9gGU8jnkRfYqFbby249TN95yIFiM8FygLZBrNPEbdktljZM3eyabBkAkDVTKc7YewaaSkDnc2B6yWztExGo1jWN8RQPqjjc26gjyoWcp30rCJkm@NQVyBo2v9I@wAN1Ptl7vw0jhJzPZKD8ri9DH6@SASzTdcTAFvMBhMlWR77BlnyvDnrjCYMS8gefRQI/mSrvmHxer8CACqUSPfwTJQ12ch4C/dyNaruueXXfJg0JTRnBWcZE7UEZhH4qqsO7DdQwPBWMoS4pJpDONLjfvii4LtMTcsubOCU7fdNR0m9SPZvhTwj1haTGJDsdWYykk0n8lSiKZass3VZv0iilBGaQyqe9oRpSWz2TSZeguwSBJBChPVDCk1AJ1SI1z0smjNMhxxyCvthWda2vOXtkSNMNVIr8Ad@NRXugj@BIU52QmMn4ghuNXb4UN7ocfnuEQ50dUunJDg63thtHtdPdipQe2lZa15rQN9pqow8qra7aEpv@hNmxCshE@k/X@rFpOhXOCNc6@@InjGnc5Ptbjf29jePa8TteCEJja/2hrmBR1pamADD5CUW7/TVgYexYZt/T9W3REEs5JL06sZqAE18Ru4KxQ7GWEAgvYHgf1wdSrVC31WJJk3u9QAG4ioC4ZkCjYzceR0haQ/ACBWSRUOI6QspquoElDPRWECZs6z66efEPJxKY7@TMPSK3jaE9CNTsTpYp/MbpdFAf8IKzFHydxE6k@8E5CuYrEJO2f0GWmai5wB6@FcLHVy7m4puJmgvs4ctzfLjiMR/dVMw8UA9ZgZDhCslcXFMRcwA9TKuEKbiq4scVKe6hJRWR19zoBxN5uEuEG5ddfFS0CCOCXMAs544@XxKxG2h99XkkK0/EYhRfSGHJNkx71hEE@eUzLrFAEOiH9qCdckaOjyIXRJEEbYYvsHjxnBFkvaE0oFf6pXVDAlEsqYMAkwt@4ryX2JxKamp@sAfO2zWrN0AEDANd2g0JRnmJeBO6KznBTpHlLWiZg3GgL99lOfH7mhAngd6V4@QmOYR6lzURyak9cFdzJuJ4t@QrOI0rbgZsiAUcbBcuCE9hUN83QRXb12xaVw1KxpA3ZbgMSe68Z0LBl/yYrG9/ZMmb@YZTKYiIZDaI1WsTp9u@q5FJyXnE4qHoX@uzKTugtdLPBOhMoWZj@FjRb3boZw7AmrDJwbCIi0xIlRe4roBmQxPmEOotgZF1gZABtTRDSR/TA@0M88ozaTGZKExT7QxBvU7D9A/dXwBLlooE2Wk2tYdAgS5YdPc5t5LHQ5jiZFMrKdmdT6GFEuZU3NxxundIgNB/ezNmNjbRFM7QciCVeP6nn7WhSWYbrKeMaZLhORpASeKWzoPtJ5Kih37mtzXBXA11TSHCkOtLKFsKrmwouueYjxp1GpZM9hSrj7q8aG5gV/yB/vYI5/GSW6o@bKvuc34mROJJYx5PbWh9qhE8cTJKU@8Hkk@ZInl6ms7pptImLHzSpamUyMLW5@2ijvj0I6DdgnT6inK6FkPmL9E5vaEz5L@4KveldtUG@J1PlbVJJsvklaaspk1baWrqI3xgKdfDtpkcXHep0li0whxYv/5NNHAlO7pyzZ0NdM4nAK@ipXW7quU@HwK77cE8giZA6Vt6PMIqrq7FSHtWHsNp6fz3IRB3X4zneJhOmk4/38KQxCIt6DVIWlx6TwbIpE0RVleaY5wI9r6dszBDUmJB8FRa8Xgmh6Out87iL/IPBg@nx6Ga0pdK81PzRX9OknmTmDRf7E9yIxjVWSz/f6HXw1im9RU9mW0HnA@KddfA6rvmgJJVINnSFRuYyRHNod5A89HPYwyOw1ML2cp3PcLefnHc5baHVm5ELxU9uWXqmo3dWX9IjE4bu/08cdsF/fhJ0TdL2DbpxXYv6bnmSwKz5eCyyQOM9hWSja9Y4JpQgHNS5kNEa5m3@H1Q2@iZNyr/nT/afZpbqq@QUUmdWEJrzRWg7daXOBWX3ulnPh2v55bLaelzw8UCweTc4Gt52dZ004ZJOv4@RgpQt22b/87n4iDVNMVIkh076J6fTBRqwFLCbvdAWyp619QLxW5agZ8HG3xodVDyi@fXSjxPYsnylyWWqxiZhiyeD4r667R1/SVOIGO3hYtiAecj4@w8sSUWUx6uIEwocKV7fuV2MkVKmUpzi8lDDWC1erfK2H3@hNHkIeq6o8lgTIo26H2YoFQEh2Nx5fun5LbyeG7trxNJM2hXv1SJQONe6yoMXvQ706Qsm5G/MYWcyXy9gOroQ3WozpVPh80rFfc6PjL9@PpCZUQ1loRtMQ3EQ8uiB/VJTCO/qtQ4bqPvUQGj6Bp08i9qN3Pl3QB08QHOvI/AcYSO2YRdYziYaNyJ6Ztx/DjlegO3Z5vtiUJizLdKpOKXdagJdd1W6fuQar/dN2GybPZBbTC@ov0FUjKD8N8JxBTiKxoT1pK52Xsr56DLguoBLapd20k0lH@d0Mk@NMMn4FIJZmyG6ozx9yFKzxOiTdPUv6VlQJa2NdrTrCdxF@uXWmhGzRGbKJhvy7DRLtLsPGTF4OOMmFwC9XAi7TwydQ7aph6ZDc7Y2R8ZrQJW9y/NL2GkJjORbbVc90MMSdYQOVVMrT7KjlwLNZuqrvDHqLDyGL5SKvcoPk/rEOotrdLgyg5fy/GX2cJTomcwBmJpbZib9NS@St5HlHqlfTW03ceDQCMTv3OiU2lamXgg3UCDvm7g78S6UUAbckwDZlOOYnVVnI7ouFQqQh@Sr@6Cx1zi7vWVrsqPPDwmOnyrBO6u45M43znfPrHGN7y0IBnfD/A4K0DHuVbHtvuci/DVuAXtOex/2cw21cdbaA79YqdOpeeu83xB3TN6Zs/oqT2LOofne6h7AEc6/LDKY5WA8vcU@xq3E5I88mdzPTtIXd3U9a@hLspDLh1Nc76ldhuPArQh6TfhHStNiBCPL5rwYMgmItHY/VDf6alDGJls0zEHapJ8D4HqaOzhv/ONz3uHEZuda6rV5nsh0PKnOFpTV9mtBkW4soML0fMNSU3dVHDH6iPKO1DGfX6NaaplWl@0e3QV0xkM6NEY6EObfsjEm@zMt12usR0q6dcwg@bwbSicZdWu2Wz1tC8VqakqjqFdp10bDvc@Oi8VwphqrrHkFgandA1oZY1TyASVYPwJPvYeGv8Cazpza785tKzxlwXD5BYAz9TKlwzQ8VD@YrV2TjQN@bjPyt1P9Mi6hVjcfZCbSIFGZTmpZkArkR@0AE1sKRPSi1YZH1B6pupNhQksrH2L6VLsDiAjnhbY4QDh84wXDwnCXSHfYFYY3R127diXGbfXBp0Kf@YirHXx9BZfWrJ18zZgaIaurxjiMXdU9pYhH1sTyT@6KJJKi8XPpDp80LqlawOb/7JkJzsXy@xq/izUeP5MVzRPW@3wZQp0fUmz65sW7qsHFSLZslS7hRZvlL5cKnKRY5hdkMJJnfnALuzcKsxuIJinm0yOcMm3B2pXwX12@xpuudPt2UEPME/vJfgaxK@Hiq29HpqOOhfn9J6Cr0H5Sulqrd2JVnARutQVm7L4Y6ITYNBsQ9z2NJu2N7uO@R2Hsxktz89GThvVvWN2jxtCAnqR2GXKknvM3Y3qOdCsj/HK3LwmtU6xMv@goNMcMpiK59x6zt9/8ZgV4XbYHwxt8Zifex8PKwQtx/1rCrdvNZCCyY8gdFlP0Z351uWA8RT0KTES@s6HtOz3mm522ftihoH6BQIOle4HGGsDxuUjxYEeYMxhVsr/K9ct0TaR5EqN/REYQc2xpGZozuN2GMdRYB7kPrFCXNXCwzjpffxNPftWDMnT@VTZf1Tiw5A@bukws/kS1NG7L0Com18eWr6w7AJDpWkMnSQeYHxsiCg8OkSssVGxEOABFn29/eos5rJCt9fimxu/oInZKszohrY@9l0Prf7zvSnHdOzSO6BjJ8S@UgjTLHE60E65R3DDtAeXjuu4xzdYGA8RDXHcd0wrxQguGlXi8VgsxBPh2knXADAXig5B4gEpfr7SZkBeh2C1Dru4YEt3o7XMmnzPKkxak1i9zrHih47rbI8GdILxmCe/WFLqlaVIMhlZilwaaywT8cBVHSTIXHBlAraj0YOX1ycBMxS@0xrdbo3L/ACY3aPDlaAtt0HrPjPIGIYaPD/GxM/IneJujb/5y7Y4cwpTcxvUVRjFgSB45Nrsqz3z9inPV@ReGwwUPLOKOEDg6/wEVXKzxkASgXrOj5qat@xs57QoDrCJ893gOeLqm1cK3rhoIMLt5w5vPF4abyuxyNhL5VYK@H7YN2BC1HZ6doqdaLSzfGj5GznBhWCGY@GssJ1ge6yt4po4HRggQ4humtd08gdL8jd/yY/t0bEBsZ3bzZ6O6wZyxNMBMp2Va7XMIZTaRfJJtUwBEkUig/gfoomRoUSg8BhupqfzhMCRSfc0HWXDj9Rt1k5YcptF8Og6HtIpa53oUu34@ZuLTL3yA@un1f/0s3TsThBO@i5ZKthSgrkg5XtkrGB0HqL92AiTlkYSz9A7U6GJMxW3vD2ARApnMjxW4fKYaQ5Er6ET0XQA2ONGcTNHFN3Uzu6xuj4dpiaGVW/pWB3tODZwWMRTyoYNHQy8MULNe11lKTrklrDkicPykCEeTVTAxY9f0ykDPCKGSZZG7DPrIZMlW7jzHXyckDqeSuxXNtxtU7ng5rb0ltoc0v6Nm2wqm6tQdZYalfUquSy1beLp4IvvL0fZTPJytLpdT9suUS8vR99lsm@B6iZM0peepLHnbR9s3S2lqpnPn21lzCTpPlLmm/FATCzdHe0dbZ@c1k7PTqAV7l3xs2NafcWXNchFtJe9Z@p07hroYmmq/Q3yx/MBeDTKlhS2jjeKxGKh4GZqAhW0lpLSEncGRNNE6i8kn5feVgPxswBCpnU05nLUHoxx2IbAbEg1rPxwgKfHmUgrTsASl2ko47EDeYTBLY9zZCmRSmIVIFYSiPWVpGIPV/YpD/sain0Ry@NkezoXBCnm5XfhxfMqziXB/W@l3gMYKH/zenMsj9ebYB6pN4B6oW6andre/tnx9mQy4DF6ktStlPLiFAEXztjTuBHNPfJLR7lEQrQiViQmUQLuFYMZXRfTVJ1bFaolhGOrzxMTh1L5pZDPmECZCt65Uy9zWkSjVALUQcpYralDDh1tFCiiO0YH0N3xKnpCYEfyULsFT0kCc5juP0nhx60GYhXkcrveEQlxIa8jdlD9Sbg9DquGYzRMUCjVA0OVN@rYDP4Do5LrytbZiInhTK6zJMvCV1dhct7zYGNlPkaxJU4IaYmXXfLKi3dvQJnaVwpN5ml7nTjHAaO0rgzwoL@APoAJ9Br7ODTpOJorTDz94hanigq/ZoaatqVgbeiYm@HgoX133CJ8ezsnFdTOuGpG8j3Ic0MDByoAClz6sj2CWSAwW4dkPb8@gpPcFDcVuEMlWXdtcTLZ0xJsdqPZZP3FRuigjqODpMTaiIrjjUt0EJHVdBt0kjYM3/x@IlJOUrQpnO8MTxpMCgNPpjyVMcGkEMLaldmT6zCU3rZgWP3AEy8RHGG2Azgj64vJJFCuqxnuDUFraKQm690ac6whbqWoRmaSuEVYI1ey5/T1AOCcOzwu1fSP//TP@L0dlw64fy7co8wG@P5Q@Drg/idujCyD7595viz4/oj7vk9jk81eViCyF3OXB3fQA18@k2bqhDLBvSaJ6uK1Nrb0m70jZpMlHduyr4wCzYQSBnlOM4BeWh@Y4obaGMF5Dn4T@niiF2@ARYCvgD9QvUGNhvJTrXoUj6yvpdNYcJzup2jbtTriZnQ6wf5xiDe3gBKWLuQLK3IaCpm8cRHSMdIu7vPlCGOxNZCJoRttUPnQbOF5DibZLUVXK4Uy5430kvJ9TvrgFXQJYEN8onDBIA0eAfFSQFxVJIsuKXE5hklxIIvIEZRpbZOzGmiDUXIASAyDDfe0HKibpiAV8LGhjhzSmMbuBKiJN3Sh@U/l9/e4iJKAiOPG@0Wmu6O/cxePPgQ6aCrYDNI5gp0g2Jo0j1kvvmeXzqVRF/fMMGC8X85hXQPc/3jO5TOcs/Bg7eytJ9HpO0uwNuzZiWHiDu8dKC2LZtPZXFouxAIcKglUUF7s6p8BJXRuEBYtVbsyB3Ztc3vvxeHRycztHQQZmQaLsEh1PX6ZTCUu6p4j4pV7kqgbO@mTVxs7LimDpfI3QSCEvxNiupjzcpsu6QO5n/Mt07N5U8RMRnLmaxHTsmNyhzYKzWL3Y9MBwE2@Y3Mm12js7v6ivl69NMIz2X@ed6NROLWMzAWuS5vuM4pMFxOLuOduBD/FmxLtlHtEKCv593V5B5u43w9@@P4N795F/xIOd8t5iA6x@gddUw9sRoe6p9I8K7qBghfMLS/IGreoMhbVz7AVmtnIEiwNE3WZvSJSnNLyiHTIbUjuBX82h7RJOHMrE92E49HMgzt1MWLX96/FEPdB9KB0utYM3Yqjy@4ZN@/Ycsoe6JoTjYUMATF92m0W0n70dgkPTKlcjJh3bMtGnXGUIjNolC5vuq2H@OUczL1DI07XcBwNgW5H5oD5VrQt1XUdg07FtoaQRQsnZC@GfYDr0ONYxdFCBS0rCYmBnhG3KBd48YSgRKrfzkdHsVRPHbW1Low40VgCRNN3suxf4KHgDRSgVzXn1QDNUoOeAnXApsmt4/0Xo9h6ibx@BbmxlN3ODzbqIUCGSZuxNW65iJwZ7l1L2PBrLJLwKNOMJSIpxmdS4holWownQ1SKbfZw6yKZPjodjVS24LF4Pph3NKufwlrBMMNZ6DluXA5yzTfdpRKgjHKhpDSjrY6ieGx9rY50gvDI7flNJCbNsDhd6CKu72hP3@ziykLFEULJvxVlSt6VSp6cmxQNpRIefccDgDApgRxPHGsfnKAiRDt9ZcCiQ7oax2YpRt7oZdRI2I4VY8kqDte3zGDxONk04EERMGdB0A65NLqDIIo3yUXTFWgkDLWNNj4@aQN2IadSdXBTJjG2hPbMTdCm0BIYC8EcFZKsEVrQL@BvDUvE7/1Mifs/lyjbEN1OAVBzo0lOocUb5AvQgmrNqk8Cp/p9AcOpWiqtidaYlPYlBnyxPkcgAto5UtydIwB9xYEtoBrKaIDatNS2BvLy2UvVMFQgEPBMH685VYbAZFYs4d7Am/BvyKMcwryIu@IEGBR08ua87cidboK6tpQuk2msfA9qzYdL1Gs6QrMZp//bdCpdvosu6ZVxGnTNWDW61KvI8dxyPL5kLEeXDNS2njxBi9r9EihzjRRMUEcAlFzSY2XgZ1D@KktGeUlZjy61K9llSgFemCLfQYIf7HTqbkm5Ty89AWUpASEWFzrRJZsutcmkUvI9lA97yFI6ATxzh7ez0L26mP2SFo9jGVJLDSzAD@nLkzgNm5cnaTLelcVcIN3ti@42pYp5LTFzHzAnoAhe8wasPA5YYjdfwwX2783LzYt7QP3jGb/EPc@MtmqodnDyJU3GfL1gEXIaZa4QMlF@qxAQcBQFIqI3ocRiIEx@/euwXGBMelrIRc3403ymHI/kZZimw/w6/Az08PSyZEl3l1vJG6Z2soWPyQulk/pYP7o@Onobu4yyEouENw8leUX6Hq8@/rrPKss@8GE//RMOL6dD4fSy/GQ1nf7w4QPMOOBzUU1VQXzwT@wiGalfRFcZq66uLicKxeXEs0gjUKxYNJuNnTBNS7NLbWC32/A1e3QJdjTMP0@fUl4w/Yd/xsNE/sLhehBEhIa/Ee5GyYfZ5aqiLMdXss@Mciqbyf7Nv1u8T9wdNdb/5vf6aXURH4f4@Pn9K3SfyPnvFhe/29hYWUkAIbn76P3Ru1qttrKVyB9d5J@uJDOL6//x/1hczGbXs@nFum3L9cjF9Vspm1mRUn/zF5Gjo9cN2wZClPCTYzI48bcIX5nl8@yafYLPdYfhP7k/tQNuBd3Nzie8SQjmKxUSNpFIPhc5@T4yv9kWmVx9uvqf//jwY9gJV7PpcwueTvhjuFAMcyc4wJdzfTfhangdwQr34XG6UqmAc/U//6@QvvoC8GDMeB1@qnkXV2EcriYrlORzuFoAh5zNQr7/189@FgpXR@FPYVmWw2P6a6AbPsUn8hOGjrS0WpRM8xle042fUeDj1yIty9lLtz0DzY1N6wX3ADe0KzMDYV67e1zFBDeQ42vhqvCzjZ@//d//9k//9o/p70/p@x/w9ufC4rMPW4ypMALjZ23t2Uw77E/5j1NJ@KS83hFGb1LULFysJBq8VB4LhwOOKTp4v0yQxPN/I1wo7F5hinKoPtEYl2G5uHL4bPTVH@YX2qVt2CeplzmbDnMbw/MwVxawb4ELhX@oVI4d/HvVxL8jG//Y6Kd8kB2ewmcR/ugfPp4XfxcpRAQTyOxn8TeQvqHwRfiiXt818O9jj/4s/Gt@xL/9T/j30cG/0xb@HX/Ev9NP@MdmahMKr6@vh@PxY1AZBdN@zecMvqlUQ/g85g2Hwr/VD1s5LBw@C0GfqMeT9/cXqe9H8XJZ/IMyVfZ8@OEuKFb9Pplc/74aj19Q8S6qopzryXoVysqLTD/frwPi@PrF@nqqUa1Wk/Xvqxfrk4lEumfP4thRn0HCav3iIhS@w7ao4M8y/rRs/M1KUpq8KNZhnC6Bi5GTHiKA0esL0B8Kf1j/EI0/jT/N6JmbjHwtX78yD/3/w8MRRGijzJVpZXqZntwGScky6llmnBmPMn3zUG6DU4W/TB@cWqYzynQzRsaQ5fFoAtXD//1D03l1aAI2E1I6o4yDiDMdeHYPD18Bvg7kfQV/WiaTGUEhR5kb@M/oKLfpZjR6ft@IXYYumPRBBa0gJUdSmUiqEIlo9Xxh8FFKRBqXF5F6OZy2Ly/TXF9i2ZUy3Yh3f99obB9sNRpp5KD1pfizePIZfCrV@Lp4PA1Xy08v15LYcpzzUo1wev3pZTWXRHchDs2ThbD1dPwbPz5KeFYXL0MwBTw/x@/57c0td5GDXJfn514s/qQxiFwUBB8ATc9NP@FgoHv@jv7bh/9l/b86Y9GLeoyx6N39epQ@MfyLxe7u7@7FbzUWjQpPdB3@MAD8mOTuvopOAroD10U0Vo/d3/Mw@I3G1jnCKuaxXqXEPiB01TDP9TJSZgzmSlGxzHZ5OcpkYuUmhHgGd@UzrdjEyrSXZamJq2wwP5CXYwSSXymXV4R7tVguF4VbLhTK5WUPKgMe4QQg1VZaZWT0cngQwzJw9o9m0MxC145Gom21g/fPPx0MYK4nlzKfP3tBjUZbsxoNDM99/nwJPSmCW1kqpTyEZIqfP0P3i8RgHnhgikXUEszq5HTWR99TbMVxrCjM9BOXEdxpa19GYhifzWQQGNOz/Pp6YaVaLayAu1CMxcrSEt8HE@3GS3Lsfikt8WrADC0SFlFycTVGofcRjGfhdfa0Chxu44fd3YeJ2mwlH4s2x2rMC5BLJR7CVgrRYrwk/iqLMbaeri4z8XdxkYuvLK8uP6vX/ZELxUT5TqnI95U7ZQ3NBvfllrj0E/dcKk@e5EpAl2KmfBlqNLZqp7UGvj0Bl6RB@jIMJIETwuXGgRW5IBtPvlS/wJrULyORtfIz3rDFPAtHygIuGQHRxYolqnAYJpJaBzdbjwgr/67Jy9ncYjo/@q6wnQHF@/Myfi4uLorZYnwZRNtyqVSv1yn08yKlueiPOnW6/KmSvJAL@XoSVZerUWc5PGDyai68HBrQ5qLVDGvj@qyFNrNFCIR2ZU1cSrdVXXfvWb01Lb19q7VVwH60X9vcPk1k1wFldqe2mcienG2EZfTmfT9F59B/vF3bOjyDBEf727WT7ed7b7bPjiDchvERiAWf/pGiDtWGejsc3qK/odJnU7OVqytlMGgM4DPq/PjLP/jxl//dj3/@Rz/@@R/8@Od/@qtf/OkfwPcv4ftH/PlH/7aUx99f/eKf/c8//us/h8D/AN9/D99/96tf/Iuf8S/5/xq@/2cg7K/FNwDHv0BKwPaHv/rFH//Fr37xT/4lfP@V@P7L6e@Pf/K/8f//KP7Q@ec//slf44/w/MEf/fj7f/zj7//ej7//8x9//x8C8r//q1/i/x//1d//@1/i///yb/7@r/6Hv//D/4kcf8Yd//e/@rf89@9@7w/@7vf/@d/93i8e@P2DR39/8RXhv/gdhHx9Ob8Gz9fU61tDfvGTyvObUMPPhRjsT//xj//iHwHn/gn3/ffgg38v6ueex4uJ06QuGfcDf87Y5zToTZlnnz1QQPk/YigEs8@T2Cg044b@6hf//C8weAL2HwUxZORZ2CUE9nL7OcD@a69gQdif//jLn/34F//wx1/@2Y@//EMUaMmVUqKWSMpfsAsBYP4r4BCw8DVwACiv4xL5IlsMZcGxuI52jJAc//ABSLoILtC/l0P5HPhwHjP9qder@Lm8SFcv05dV/qmDP5WuYkgqfZnG@FQaNXq5SsigVPEQ5AzzoWVuiIij/QG@o9BKCXxomojDEBTnUXGI2oizSqUSD40qEEeg4MU0I1Yt4qQL5xwVwIuJeJpEowhaLRttEBZIWYkfs8ZyZcQTxjGgShgYFgiDjiU5K8WLlS3IsDLaYogLkcdDH@D5oVItVkZVRPcDFQFwxDcgS4CqYOlG1R/AXyGcAB8abf0ARSlW4vFqEUIqVFXKLdGgPOU8VY7qHmdUbwyHCTA8nj5j7DtJLkp87gdtwQQ0/sZ96KdkAnkK8ZfxZVEd@ned9F3G9NDQI6IPD@PxTzGY0gsAwJtM4n4s@CaTWJpnED3iqOKULTziHANQLi5MSF4ADdPxUJzaN04eyB/K8HWf9WrAg@iwOktLS@Bar0o56RCmEsy6XrMdxcLlClKS1phUKEkYjNtb1KUjmmwsby3Drwz/24u0RZWTYzm0FEFdIMLcPJLxnLlihqn0btWoLstU8jjBhcJ@OFdwac0JNNMVFgtF6ebxGM1V1cEAnq/s7oY5AiU0IUkJucCtyjExlX1nrq1VfpBXVkPwJP8QLz0X129DM@CLsFLYy5Cg1bsk9Th0gr5SCFWrYt2MyaHqyfYpJDg9ZHI2k2Kgud6trGZX8iv5bK5QyK9m5ZVCaaWQL@ZAxBUy@WxWLq2slIql1Xsq0jMQFYm15WZ@vfoPZj7/zT@Y95kfip9Q9S0bpVjyPlQdJZPpLJW4IudXy@MKlIOCQlXSxLiOPr5L4nbJ0CVtz7rDnUBQrNBdEtl0AT4stBBiCxAEH0CLKwZMLGPvHZbFeh6@ToKv6UlyHhghFroERuDYQoPJTwib7QnImicyd@YLvjODzlM8zHQAOUAjGGwfd046Jjs1@Q69DbUVWhfHcKqhEC1/XABJ6yG8rf2iHlpPe7HzMW32@DvWNi0TNNyfDrOhGNc8akvDuxNbjhe1q@ANSXZfc3oPQJwN@nhsR7V@Zxi2@00oIJo5OcAG/Fi6ac4DWGVnRw/U8pV3OBLXEel0JIAf7z3fPQ08T7drm7uhAts4PNiaeuQFUJ7tb@@cet5VHusmzXso3m3v7097xQNnKYssv5pIgHSEH3wm6EPP1NL3LoicenjczSRY44S/YGBk2tBZZeDphprNs6WSDFKugDPG1UwpV8qXVltWZSN@PCxKTxclmI6m16sthXVVVgQJg/vGIAWdf9Ds0C7MYPp41TqeyndCltqG2cytQUc7mvjCpOGAPRgIDwxCp6V1eyDZbk0XINRUFAbfb/1AejX4cR4PcHgeFDYTo88Bx5UyrcMyoRRZu7KlYr5YymWLiWKpuJKHiV4@IWcT8mpxtZRJyBm5KBeK@ZKcKK6UcisgAyEWKBwKg6zQOuk0iHhZkuipGS28DnUd75U1U71qKMyNBTCu4psAw4oXMCwyKVe8zEA6KYR7YplWWZTwXZsZfJMlIFRYi4V3djYzOzuStIEetOltZiSpjZ58MZNZ3ZAklWI2QUxnJcnkaSAKwBzuyWQ2NiVpyBHgAU5J6qFnu4AKqSRp6Nms7exgPlfoyWJ6ALvmMdyju55VADPQk8uRRitJHz10AFfjGa1QSbfRg3lizA6P2YQ4SXrulieTAQzHHI5j2HXrWqtJ0h731GoY84IqnudFfYmeGn0kyQIP8KAkdcHRtWDqLUlNcCInSlILXK2xAmF9cOFZP8NRJGnMCYQkkqQRQSutawmUJxGO2ezu7io9p612@Wds8WcLigYx2mi4vdN8/rzZ7TatcW37@THGvHixq1yNh1az2xTJmg34mJAGYq774@kPlHGv0VD0uTEvIcaYimmMGyqWraF8hDKJTxcz6TdeQMwLiJm3UsKxwacPoE38bPThuaE0Kcb9UAw9R82mVEYedcYDFW0q2GVob1E5GNJXWpZZRhdo22wxEo0kxhdyPfGpTDGsz1g0dpcp3yNIJ0qv0UBhCKrN3fhiVMnUQceWy2juiS72n0pyKS@tLSpPoyN0F6Q10LJXpNgavoLE7ERYJCk/BeFWWJXWluEpPZVy4BxFM5EMY/ATu1itP5VWEYn09GlSgrKAF0AUSCitlhBhaRVG/PI90MMBqdocOmqjEY3eqsp1LMbrxF9bxM7Pz2N3fD@VRnV0yp3oKDGq8NIwLVb@BIWfxtRWYWQbthzT4vi6QIFPTzNrVEnIvihB7iydjq2jQEIRAk/fjI3GaM@AHTrHgxB0CNLdMUOarL0WOkWdj97px/DccxNfg0OHamEywS9goJfWqKABlkKhqlCCTtWRk9pVcfdKK5k8n/isr58DHB7OxcOHB8M@22C3lAseRXB3YzcqG4AyUzbwogAVvUuj8ChUbSuOAlOhjbvh2pqAvS93KxeI4DP@rCel8@q5VGfBfPOrGSjVmdFaX7/4XAc1EAg6DisVOVssj8J01mR1pRyFSUesYqsfuTL4WUfz32KjkuFq4ZI97F9kFgty4i7ZSN7riu0syavZtYvh0kVSri8uZj5316X3VamOmaPCSH9BEyVI/TKEuc3Bx4lwR/sA8Wwtyd@iIhcLsRRuiW@YnQa9z4B9CAwHfsJBGQZ2XQXtRi5lywIkNBCME5VYFF@BxPfmRCOR1WwkEouUAWoRgon/YnfELhFg4sgTYF0YjoB3S1mIt1RnCAoPdCq3mF4JuJJckEPh@1BbswdspRQK34Xu7@7Xq64@8ZKNx0o86XqfMNaNw3QpTesuuGKzSK5kqvqM1Sq17nGtLEBrmzSpSYfYJT/xlUwvfuvqTny9@j1/XuKaHmQT4sShpc/0erxKRoCQJElhyTXNR4t5mAmhveGHMF07yDbvOkODriJYe4XkUta4hnRRj/1woOl3xVyySqp2FPrafTi@nsb1wlQ1TcRqHdJyeihsmMKJhloHugb0z3xewmmXygYnpe9Xvy9@/@rs8Oxwhz3LrBXXipwSl3wmlJAjcgQo@wwUA@14OxQefDbz8g/Gi3J4bRDJrURyE5rcZUWcd44iH0QvcC0DvvULmFDVY@CqVOSn8uqaZoulhuiaPRyoVuypXMiuZWHMjYXtKp7GzK6GgUrokgur4XqYY11ZjYGbzORZOVxNi2B5VYZ0Se4DRs@HbeCK4qsPn2GOLN7aqmXJlU6Loi7dr9/Df/X@AqaR9zSbvKd//EnDzz0HoH9M4Hro4X8m4HwYP77@Q3Kd/6/Tz@YhL7RUgGYIf6hUobW/b3zfCIfCpUg1no7gG8j5ZyRmaKjcLRv0p9rL@Pe9H7Bs2/ay5wPvMtSZ5asyA3Uwnb6Mvc6CIlgqFYqFcOjXs5/0MswnlxdqLMLv9eFCGG/18477RCbeo4QmgOWF5NbJ4eZLmGmDFFYNfA8m2zw8SGEUvqrRP6/V0lXF0sfiXY1jhELhfbp5hG9zP9s6ojTndFKPQmmmL3JZ2muviReaJG6YnMrh8lE@nVlJy3kmF9cyq2vZAlNAENl4Ml@4ljApo2ptmoMxV9@jmzFKvFBDGIzb12DuZKtr7PnRPqWgQ/vLC1vbrw7Z4cH@u5QbysNPd/dO2Mnhzul57Xgb6vFq@4RJtRO2dyKx873T3cOzU1Y7eMcg@rh2cLq3fYII0iEUYqhOcIJ5ujRbt8d2GnUNmxTqiWDbbF2rzmS4Yg2UNF5TORls4FssVLzqfTJ8aMAEtB3U1U9qC3zgZoheabetEB4R1FpsARX1hWXVwn20Ui9jr7L88O2njJVfZK2Vg8gqa2UOjNz6KtMz4o/pK/3cMVtcXLw0JG8ECFbDmyoEg3BzOYT5Zdp7v70QLaywZZggZFdifszB4dFCxvUtnB@fLshe3PHWQtbz7O0s5DzPNvhWPN/O@dZC3vNt1F4uFPxkB5sLq55va3tzoej5gEkXSj7Og60FORNyiXVjau0FelNXdGdvf5stA1CsPBGL9hd0TAUDIaJDw@b3NdDcaHn5tmcmSNNsjqeg2@qXoF3wCagF1FMukK71BFs2B/DTV/sADMlCnuqnWN1WQmDFK11gXAndhRawQgtYIYBfwJPCCMcWKywbYxC90OEr2VF@xVeCSWc2nQf8zmbrqC9UgRkSdEcMnQuFFKp4ZV9o4V6gjHbIRtWhza4ECvo0kywpFsPDZAdn@/s8MxgZLNOKSgTJyCPNwWkOABtUEX6x6hDKG4c3C7UF0mpBqBX4WsHQ/URrhqZbE0kB9VxYaAGCSereKHqCoQKWwBVSxIsevkkdgCEa3Blw8VN00WgL69pVnRYVKIbE3D7c4TXENdYKm2zlGMNMiVIUzbe/f/7MXN@lM@m1Jr1GhOMWyHmxOD5e0grCxjBswT2@SBB0VJtSLiDHxOOQGqpDcYF6LQDR4ctPdrulrEJGmQh78oTKsQ6@UoSywHRxypElEQQRCIIR@RCZV7RFKm5sIb2MWyD4O7mRiDiO8Fsjm2PvVgqQrNMFnWpVrxd6zblgwNSlPCWQRVSnjW0N7ly2AX4Uj8DJCdaEbpJgbqRcwEicaSSYmmAdCJ6SqQ3NAM5VLV8muqwAnZFa/2CLtxC/goXCeQDVGOTeGjUYCIsn2H2J0RcWmhZM4MouFMhDggK@RaaJIiE43OPpjrco2TLvL8iWmPprUu7trLl8xFMDOwhOI7LiTIbziqguBVZ9oBn8Ahn23wqg5yzJkcXjAsLjMgG2PQmXTHK4e5cvv1CJ7elaLH5zLVAsP1iL7a@sxm9WCxjWfBaBWoCIjwLeOEDTz2RrZuehgLGQUFBtfhoKGEB9XoI@PoHgK9LDkOunT357ehik16a7MvRbaEEuFXiSSW9r0tue9GL3hRCFwZwgu8I@sya65AK48PQ0K4KjzWXlZMLOpJcMERWmumk6ngTmOQDPoajkYMiAs8IYJUjKxhvulT6@Z6XCajuNvYPt08lYxJeyG6LgPXyfOeURmwQTBcJ4O4qemFeiaAeJwPXN6BHPI0H0bJycHm/XXiWgfDG27veAaR0AfkRPmKjBvZsDhBpqC8bjdoJFT2psOcaeYMkSTFgL0PPVWeimrQKqB3NsDwdZyirDQTz/ZE8KY48MzclKirJojH2@vIQhNbPK5P7gc66fM1ZzbTbOraKyy/F4OoiQ8q6AOeBdkysbCAnsqeD9H3Mzu8pk2IqVY47aA417lLFm8VO97nFso2HRPeM5MGlSZpcZHqlF2SJuxIBxcVK1eVyLpLER@QBDsRtDGA7nZO2Kk36O7EmxroLFy9JWv7UsX9JoJ8uS5GVZp0xny/BrYfCD6VJo6hwvXSxiDpyBgkddReThAK0pRxhkhULcyhK4Xypq4rstnNga3QuCMqXRwHsMG42oreodfK/20GrBkI/qsi3A8IOxKR5JHQkdk5GCPKg/TUa0NTyaitdNwqgzhZBe712h2@yilGMo5JXMdtQBlSpQDDSU4VtggxnCBHvCD82KR8YCJY6tCa14R8H@4CK7mLgSiOMY2r3EnGAQz7OhHpvOifPYZk4c3vw2L4l7lHlO3NWwP68EIBgeiBGHEefEGObhvAT8Rh0/on4RIOBFkMD1ejQ2v@mhX022eOBKJKL/qTVUxf0@e4cBFgTlUnBgoK3DWyowbUvDG8OnEXnHoSFldBQLnMz22Crmc5JitzRtGr2LSSCio4V0KTYbrbV6gPU7OVuMJQIIAxjxyr6@oj@EkwWQQgnnIAnzV8kz1/5pe6iRBafx@ulTeLGA0YbpnZ/AHDwCj7E@LDa@C7yAd0J5MR4zz@lyPrq1WcahcLTPY/PLE7dnPQTtVkKOBQn6m2af/Nbsk4H8sU/@pKwr7GKyHPV4wL8GAX4d3Q7@kzJySz2ZW@ybahzkGlW9foB98ZaTQDb8doPJbD00QgJ5POVWhdBjwFcKCcQVRPQN8oWaT5y9npfaH3@WKywpe2m4xPN7A9nVA4UP4b0MjQZeaNpo0E12jQZalhoNiedAAy8OeMFBV3Q2HpcCLbVhUmxUSipSQkomayebe3tJzZAS/BLmimQ7pqU28EIqKYGrjhWJBFYDYXqqPqhIYtuXYjNKLT2cRy2QB1Twy5kQEM9lz6BM/JtKv5xdK1gl8yuqZE5l5t@e@BW5HVNueFD8sZwsfg2Zm9Em3ZSFV49ZqoaChl8vLV6hjFdKTNxkgCZ9UQSer02WPhvvj@BFokcDw0Rb40UM9KLqCiNrn@TerCLNXIQiejuaehCBz6mc@6QjegkNo1u22qrQs8g8lJL8GxZFwVKipgF@dxU0fjGFP6BN3rYiyptwbZM2mjGniuoLFnOAlb@Q8DIWaIAjcwC/3oUs4PauZAE3XsqCQa6oAzfeyIIpOsIhLmcBF13PAk9gb8m/DbKvjLT@EA03wSP/QpPzi4VDPtaERn2KnJR@nKIIkdLxWt2owBuLS2sSVN2mq2Cmr4NB@Hk3wsTqoVkhS/cXYzEDqsM8pHPvmIklfguNFFDEUDTbojSQNiExiSshlFZeq8PkM8A7rohB9XkqzORWT0QENUl46f3xKnCjTGVieoEUgckDL4yfgFuZgi97I@U@tuapIH6LBaG44jan3Lhv88GCBzG4ilos9MhM6v8386Rgk/wXOlX6/35SNDP1@R1PZR6ZwnzzbOW3OC34rwr9f1Xof4JC/1vT5h9QyadRzvb4KXX9i2r4t6tfJPPGMGxY3Rs0vWV/ih72W1IEVr9JD3BLfSE/pgt8eXx20WSDw/pPHKVDv06ftgvnO2atVjvty9bx81q31qsd4@U9G5n9@PnVysbW7cbzjXZta6v7ort5oL4u1lb2By/fFt8973z6qIL2vnv44v0nfdDqhd4eD27P1aPbnFq0a8Phx73dsbO7cdbfPMm/W73NbOv5zob6cUu3t16dvn15@jx/Er/9@OLoxad@pm8fdTJKqZ/bfVV4szk@N0L5G@2svbOvHfZP2ttn2f7@lvZuJ76Z2T8pvZYz@9u373Obt/F8Jr03eHn4/Pjsqrn9Xj/e23/X3vxoKoWP17eDvXS71Nm8On4TOsy9lnc/Hh52t7Ol57vp263OoJ3J7upW/urt8dHG2bvd3ktlu7@TPyu9vRofFXqvX984B/Huynlh@MpeiRu116@zL43nNzfbx6GmYp5aOfXcfC0Pbm@PzFJ/VX15sNvtv7ZkI32YfxM/6Z/ebm1v6B9XR7mzd@evb1dO3g1fvX7x/jCjnZw0t5XCoNnOnlydroRa/dxe/OZs@6yoPG@fv@7f7O3m322lX/XUg1r7SL9@3t19b54c7e/VcvbQkPc3b/R3z3tXr663Nvd08@haN2or6bx@2n53eBg6e6E1t9Tdt/aL2lXvXTq/cb3yLt4ePD@9@tS7frFxcnZYzI6Oxhlz0z5u7nZGW8eFbDHd0j8ef@qYr@Sz1/HCzdWLrPau9skJ5T6N86V9/Z3aN17EW933o496On4my5vv9z69e3eye2M1a8bZxzc7x1fWq7ZxaB9mjl@8fNXUr4vO1eC9cXIitzLP1etX8YwSGp3t2tBG6qmSXz3t778ejLbMj8d77@3Cp/jN@XVO3bo@flP7eJxp3hqDt4a1r/U3M@1DpfbGdLaHo@et0s3Z9a6@//HQfhd6tS3n8ztmx97ovFkpvU0/j3eun7/dkE9GmQPjuLNSsA7evD7XtO3e27NPx638zptBse8Y3defzvrb8e39Ue@TWsw09ZN310boLH9yfJS9NV5qfWdn9/hVwTnM7L85au@O5dprVb41VjfH@a2RVcidb7213l3vGoP0O@3j8Cij3sTb7wbOymut2Wm90Vr9l6GTF72zg6M3t3v5gvW8b2gbR8XMwf7u5kG3vfJyvPdquL3fvGo/33urvh2cFq6z2xvnha23Jznn9PqlU2rd9HNHxfip3ne6Z/HQi2FvuHp0bn18M3q/Uus31dyx/s4cr8r9zReD7OhNbfvwU/f6aGAeyDvZcfps37zWM59Obz/t2oXaOF4cnTl90zmVR3n5dSh3@2ngvBi8eH1yuPHi8P0LZUXTzpWrkzftTO6smNZ6Vm6vUHgub@90@h/7JVX@tPUqp@T6vbi9f51ub7bP3pxf61f9l/2rVqhYslsbe@@HirndzMqZdxud7by6v7F/Kqtn3ZcnK1sHmaO37aOzj6PT9ubb4dmbQy2zffWitN9deXv8pvRy9f2pfaqcm29fWgehUTFn2nKhlL/NnZSKhz3rJHd@VXLev7wqbOjnTfnFXrav7mjW2@K4eD341Lvt3p6omWb3@dZH5bizDZL07Cij5IfXB6OTUO7Naf9mdbARf3fdevnWkPXiubaaPv14Vbru9V7ebrVWzmufPir551dq6WQn3dR38s/jx5uvj666W@efiivtzMb@G@XtaLvnvAu93tW2rkrn14ejsfx652Tcr2UMPX9zcp6/OTU3Ts53T4q9V02r09y96oFs6I/Prm6HN7vqam90W3zZu3qjZPbfFjcNe@UoE3qh7vXbx6cv39binaxacm4O3x0Mzovno/yronleMg@L2sta5/no9WFnO7M60M5PR2fbvfTGptYvgkw50s@szcPXu@/PXwwyoaxR2Pi0aeZXP8ZvRu8K5@mj@P7wXes02z@3rN23mrXz9ubo7cuT2l58rzl@fnStHL7bzp8cbG7aL@I7WkEd7@Zu7dpmTu@YIbu/MToYWYNS7v31fhdGArNdaj8/zZ0bdq3Wud0rnmzXas/t5t4LZTR63lmFMQI/2@dvzEro1/xithC/k40/FH4LRKhvd5vmCOQlP0cWotNCITotFOLng2iPNN9//Ov0cug0uM2eXlXKDTzDJihrrG2i8pBie97tqfjyhATrm5BcQ1fLHNAT0YrzAG2c8OnwS/YqPKlGL1pTRwPd1PC9NHhHPs5JLZUfhwP1JRU6NFh/jPNNR@3zzf8avlpGXHZK1@rzN/jQZYuhhVaLua@jS9FVnt7L6T6AAjEwukm6u7XLkslWR1e6Njj0Nrk@hE68u8UxB11T0PiBWcj7DUXO5MXWVFRXqXCn@Eacg@dMN/ml/e6MQwFlYkw3YKCRim7BUPFttrZ2o@pjeguD2k6F@I7Pr9oFGQzDzd2TYXTh5NTeUFA3VGtqA@iAJ3RXWtPLz/CCkmfLabHEispQQ7GamoMvRG3wlzc0eI7unrfB5N5DOkAqFmi5YoSaDV3VmhDHYkbom0qFFKNN5njwwBHZo2qIKqq723B5eUAoad8V454A5uXBw7i1fve3hXoCd1tTJ/CaQKsh0IoWpGfW7L@zaZOjB1QO8cX67bd7pw3xqg6@xXDisM0DOy4DVC67vkGZ1yBQflHy2W2ZuMMAio9mR37TMVT1xuS8LNG@R9weCa2NM2x/tyW98BuLjtgGtBvlYqXOdxBmaOueS3AvzRPOCU8CpXriE3RBbKjweOAr0/ENmhxktr6IuGOpKgHQbk73bMjUZr/fMu890DJNXTGu0VXmW2VhvmC1Ao1FLyEI1ANNWV5dxP5JmiNgvSGptw3WL6hkec1CAGJDrNvMZwZ2Z9pvj2l4C3tZo30M8/BmXbputqJ@9LK75YbXLebmxOGnsjpES2IHd9aa1phnhOaZaLkMILhPh2SCari7VQO1rvjUQHS0qSdQCuDbshuEp9VVv5wJ9nhpeVaLxA60A2h@UflmIIS68IpV51k9LAuB3rFgZSaS@sRxtxCBM73MHHMAROgIjoNhjHiE706doQrf6eVxEeN0usjU4Z89DXrW@MZd7FAqmj1RhMSwG@MMfapwXqERtOp1HczKZz1qKNzBjU2oES8yDWb4GM60eHyinQLILzSkm8ziRO3onFgQQ16NBOkF7QmG9sRBa/CtuKzDd3BxWoemSLQOGX3@7HUY8HrceOSeDgSW8F6/jAzOOZP3ZUHQsut3O6HnphifKJ5UvZ/dS08nG2ECbt4OtJGqR0FgNvAVJAMGQWLL0mDAHQThbV@CYGxsKruQV4uLUUh1QXDpYp09YVF5fT26moxS0HfFWMzrjCJ5NpA8kBiEdLXKotnlaM5NvIKJAWVuEsHKfARZjmBlOSq7CLICgZwHDFzFICTfsSLn2knExQBiD299EgZfZDIn9@VsXK6vrxdxj2cgcCpxdn7Rl3PxLCTmqBfikzEcLY8IhNcnawTIc9nAOBJAsRLPAQqedXwyws91KsLLNJjnSn3u4PRbU17ccxru4EPJ8X2KqnVRxPoip/JN6QMG7oFjiUB8p9WA3mzlh3GWXkY2Bx2BuiTk1lPx0FSCv9lMDFpAv/LUqBg4HEEQKAaICC4eLcGuHhvrmt8@2CFwhwx8vM4JJidYEaYhIFFAYhQhMYgQooHWbbT6Aw8OhuJijO/45gMYZXKAK854fgDaCdV@NycSY5x8uMIN@MSbpWgM4fSNQoLG/t4GPt5sH@OO2b2D59CEC1iPBPN/3WoucoxeFTcVg7/tQnM0KALINj6hEXXlTTWZPwa6@QtsLnIBP42dJ6TaIQTjiYV2SHyhOQ3NFNg4KV0@Uh2iI718yQMoxsowz2C3KlN0JMeYvzS2yN/RRIfeKDWRChxeQlFApBDS7PS4dnCyc3j8iih31KjtH@3WEDNMMFuK1Wb0FhHsIIah6nxQ9egZwuEXJDSvk9J0X3nB33mMsPx1dJx4ANigmAaFTpcI68uZfgaeB89LQBLFgwalotFWB3Nw495VD0xUxp6DkLciL7UYCkWZ5o2ENODNjoSuHK2ipCNamqptRBxgbHqrimJweZJ28W3ALJNeSUc9F/WoLvGLxd/BlcvSi3mRj@zhAFeH1bYUJL/Saqk2Hcf3qQ8oVb1DmQjJEiAUhMyvvS8/@NkUb@wVOOi9hDToZjy911dzJ5VF0B457X6SjhtQkDgWV0e6c9VKUotEzvw9wROqozapMj6UGc/tiud2BblxgcuuphUyrX5xNaGIzSOP5pLniuvGrmbG1RNvKzm1XAc6vd3Da27IFsKlDjUYNhNd8WCOJ2TdE7fJnri92O@J85W7x5UyQdhJjUwMOP74KSbM7TaQLTpj26CTKzT7GlrY/txjqLfooZGSH3RypxgET5zSAHXahXPFJ56hepAzEBNIQzotcyGyq9Og4uGLCoQs6ZYnFtA16BSmsApoBkgL/3CaqCupkqYtJoqBQBSrYhS22m4nJ0h/MLPa0we6EAhD@YFD/1QCP8bHMyqik95pWCHUyCG@zkoRXFdNJiFBjNs1SKcBcYt1oOJpzvxqFGerISrn6mQaPwGDok64ZS4KEPQzzHsg1M28PLfegXq4h@EwcSxQsUxZnKBwT/SeHbGcnMsFjv8enh@wQsE/HYxXY7GVbMY/coyXZLFCKfST7GS@PYHzI3Yc0aDIVsgzOHUHXVDVdejE/NHWcOjHsvFp8Yg/xmVPuVrmM1hbiGMxNNisj29Lb6r4VnBcr3WYPJJToQUQiqeB9827gzcAdoeKpRiOys9YoiAXK7uYISVEHVa1bP4uenobO0h8fFk4DAuWyg3AENI2W7RJEnFQOmjpYZ92IyVQYbhRLbwGQHPEQf8FkjmCHbhoqHImcANd4VB1eYOTUIgE6tFoZOFkpGEZqcdNL8KVJXXldD9DpTzdl2lIc9/cigUg8gpWIRpzd2hBEHhmmKH5@LJ4fZXbJT1gX/TPMw3ODjJ8curOwwUaPsbMzvy1@hxjDHFXKzgGjcQmJkJFdarH3DNwJAHcI1At1w7BgegxqtPwRLj4bBQpiO9y17gtnJGMIC2CRikaUizkOtylI25Po@gF793VxM8V6H0xsTNgLA7MeccjBQSyfIxDiLOR0xDYPznEKIgDSsE76nLa338wQhzeeTcU38Qh7iwc3TExL0AEfF5LahcvPz@TNr8Woo9SpvxI2nRJKSoW6MvzwXiVBRjWLgAGhSJ55FbKBTs78s@9uYBUejJIPVb4idy@tvAiuxmgCUp8ZdE9QtwLW908pJC4b96ofJFKbKsRamagfbiSBI0oGIF4lvq9MFUIGrhSgZeuGUjBdWY3jStJKEYc@p0VOQLKcyxn3ePArkD3zJz@ud55FeWc7FbVrSa1IL0/WtcGNDRO1lV0i2Bdk/JsZVcDlXVPGU9UViRy6zl7v4MBjo5u3vL7F3BAkcTJZem7doJ918bFEBESHKNcasyTf5NnnQMd8vuK3yO9@nllpUOznof3VbF2iKI9yO@YDvFm3E6OLxCmIUBGcNMou5vreaqFBaHOgNIzkS4bE2Znj51dFJ0OyGvaqo@Xoe5nXUw@xxCWCvuB46Eh6JNqTQC7YJ9JzmMBYh4svkQ9CBvgIiGZJzqpyx0YEY@L8awyYQ32D1A/yIhBLEJ2Bo4oP5qeZMpsKcYYx4fJ@TjcJGK49/t/OViQ8YMFQXLQGpEY67w1I34lwv1vujLq624DobmB3jXIws9HoYgJ/S2fcfWA6MDXF7zZAZ8PBHUDoWi7yiAatkCBh7kxPxqdYJD7g/D@DSMf@QIfHs2DlHQDSDAZXTURFEi8hNnAtGgQmMTMFpNahyg64G0yWW5qSDKEeNh5NZ4MLhBZOpvEZUDujMsztZpAx@iQM1njyvzyD1Jl8RprmqcGb//Ahl/GyuOSpT/PGuDhYHe3A6HQ@gNd5Sd35P1G7XDPu9qKiTeuq7aJQXbKtLrpW@1aS3PA0Im4tiqpDrGf4yVVPKaxfQZDGV445aTYico3K6Dei2rZB5pOqsPYB0yEN2AZANzpgMZrtFR8hYZzi/sHBAI7FSwsRCs26OGmwcam2fRLr4iTObwACSq7DYXvAmGGTXo9fEtxbHWspjFhuqnDT1/BK4nTMCVPYw3Th4a6D6lPoEuoqSvlRgltBQpGJ6encqVL6EJJtB1RjIMvnKbdI2hDcOil600T2sbbnyomCXSzomnoY2bgFQBdBd98zugduJAVct4tVJN23IpFHdryoNI8YiVTKpCwt8UIR@lw/E6lIC4fC/GXpa7h@Q7bRHaxVNqbSskn9rRM7cngHXNyEwWf50@GtfByri/v0/C2eKTTgbSm8TX7Pubt8aD7v4DsD@38SKfRPDrQlTGTbhW6DJptrqxmCms419K6BrEh9ha8RCegsaujAb5yFDcG4DjuptXVG1VnOWzGN5o9BMATZwhVCoUHltLtKy5gNLfGMJvAHV00v5440e9HmaY@GdLBcxPMn1HjyTTGZB8bneASowoSUwSLcUGNgdSCn6e45dk0B2wNHG21OezSYIDnstwUeDpKSTQxgRKrRpuxp/BcgycUHYu0DP0YO3/Fu78K9xOZGruAbl5n7gKFVA5RLaDrV3jpy256HDkQLLCiAwM2X9WAEWGZNcRklFsJABrHsCiHs7ndkxbPXZC2uXeIVhvKkG8udmOwigNx1eODe0qWWWBPCYgEvG8KGZOuwEqnXctIpIYvj3U9GxEeS1ajKHf7JiI@6i175HD3L3T47pN1uhOM0S2eRM5Y2d1VL5fZvQuIe0BQw8GdJcmIu3MANUwL12b8HSlAesmdhT2GNlCA3BcgqeGQzXBcClSDb/Cuc2uXUEGmo@W6u4YF4ZVM2aUGf9e01/7@YtYT3poLVPFFenP1HRPqtNTiCzG0SiIWmCbKioOX4BHiDo5LDPFRzg8UMMkNwppIRtOEZ1DlBeU2VxAWqHMmaUhJsBHrovWdT58SbCy8eAN6iF9ynEmMK3LZuxVZNYb9O5yMJHiS4SCBwPdMBWlfDuGvmNFZPHOvd8MoQWIdBXmIBAUGXbjhaNq4yySYfF@mnFv0Qiku4kGPmOX9uXuxLg3Et3YBUxH6r/NhYu27tpTg@eGSATlk15GtJ/zcOBG9Uo/G5nV0lBiD6GB4HqkqZh3oFsZ58o4DUXRHiVinEQIG7bANBdcdG0i7qHsDGWuMKjBBaowraMPj93@hwsu7BV0gg/BrDACTSQSEGSpzlV2KJzKD6BvF4xgPk7rJ@OFgDWfZbvqZeGw9ws/TB/Hf@5fkER0ao0RjHHP3pUCKxniZSOBtT7mfqS4V7zeo70x5p@o7Qw@vvg/Qw6vvLD1/Un09i/FbqggMMfTAOQ5O2Z/CjBrfVe8GcjvFU4aBGX@E2no3nXo4wPfWTKWmNxPMpjYHA9PG@5rnl4DnOacQFB8Ihzyf8jzWwA0T5DQ3H8nFDHQ9vG3eDvEubpmoL0bJjW8H5OMX6JM6t22LMZoCEHOJLPqeNznlhwxiYigJBrki0asfZsVlKlcnQG27pv3FFRbIquwVnCrK52CMEnu1jzHuDeAIVJ22L0Jp3CRIqBibl2SIegemm06CYfOTCKoL@TiZCqnO5qZyGxFTi92VriZEYkfa47MkX@uWAmtNDZLOwK4BfcKbx3r23lHcZXDeGGTpjcTdURqmYnsdsrZt8o3Y7EhYp/DYE6jwTs8yh90ew4uiUAdEWL6lvGOido/aJWj1@ErIId5Vs@Zui4v61ffsx2l2NmAwyafz89hzXx2xTVT8m2O0JXNbQDQwTIgdVgsLru604Ju0F0jSe8B1bujjFgc/e2qzQAG2kB@gCK/QEgfZHxM7zcnYHcSSsqeBSIrjqP2Bg5q1xquA1feTDXAZxk@IGoB7xxcpKwse6PzCcjYOlJZKFyzuPrDKvNJm5haSjqFOF7Kpoqkv80jhuBVx2nYDxcHcsTRb6u@g/bxc@eo1zPu/wJqQqcuVCYJTYZKLm6NB2cGjeX28fhxv1uCcCjNwQHlgWjg3HCfmYr5Fexz1LuUW5l40VUa4eEoUpwfz2RvcaDQ3Na249RRoKjo6gIigBKRa8bUzXC/Dd4Rh6lc0HfUS8wmwTaoc3jvLi2G2cJXZTTxLCctsqWrbRpVVQV6hckbxeIPoru4qYVtTujhDhJm6K3rd4pA9mmaLPa3FT2VsHmFRLPXjULP4ZBtLk4K2pH0/wAqbPbV1TbD40hwfe1IzkkA2w0maHWZ/HCoWmhxMi8UjdkjIeD7SHIudONN6lBBQ5Qlg4rzKrBISAEb1E6@CnGIr116HphpX5tFmHXyBRMQWL4cQNiOkbdD2g1aTFAN55RlkYHjWxQldzSY8gel3gnWGOspic5DCOJSEk5UN@lCxbC5W@CWGE9UMeCaAuGCdjA1gFNtQLA9DlIZxMRJzSfNl8NIMNGb1AHCSQ3tzrAB9PaIBKSfoNrG8Q4eCfPsFRJP9PIr8ZrswHdxrYaliCoFpMrEEZTKLlobiWayGaSSDmDnYLGKAQ7DY17Zf5f@l9mOoABkoe0DA4PF3tDC2FDRWUtHF7BN6OtUSGVlUBeRAf6g7iqGaQ1sf/64ZIbRAr34UujMEjcn7Tngn1XGchvHZWRpfBsD20oe03Q33JuBEHYR3dn8NY6RTIWqw4fqmGGeZLo7B2An3zTG4TBQ9xbh9EYeDo7snYCoGr0xASw9uE3DojFeCbxsA0UnHxQwnRencDXZKyxmSEO2ZuLkC95QO0R6EezwsPCJGTYICG@uCyM2BavHMgNvG5pC54zPwq3/VJwhI/65NDTIVQx/hR9mM1UK@5wMJ4EHcAVS45bCrBtKA@IWCAzjZjqDc7vDWVIWNAgc3vrqFL3bEHChbeCJujZ@B8zP8ybnxVTi0@WKWiHsqXQavFYDOFrCS8X320UUxv4@5E/2p/U@kMru2LheWM5TY248rCbSrYtYs505gtTJttIhqFdypsY4nLKBfAuiFVl@s4FoL37VBtjNsxVtgEFWxWj2oErSXhgzjWESnttYmssEcDs3e3lXmNgP0FcyVK9DGsN/EK2k6RC/vmCate6CRHECiPuoY5ewfvdRIwmlx4OdL3OpJ9uN2zOtbPCual@DkBwA9OxKOoKJMZL8UhEG/v7PJo04nKrxoCskiWdB/IQLxmhJxH/1MVLbu3lzvTfmy5WmM8iMYY77xbOpIGBq8nMAWp1vTuuYrR2h2I8nvKBrZvXEtkG9YxkSuRQ8X@W0/jq9kuMY5/7Um1J9xYOkp/097z7bcRnLds/AVraF2MSDuvEgUweFSEqldJpLIkJTXLoiLxWVAjgQCMGYgAkthK849lVSqHG/s2LGdysVOKnlNUnZclTzkff0P/gL/gXMu3T09gxmS0q7XldRSJRLoPn36drr7nO5zCa6@5FXUFMCm2GODHjacCgeY3/BqodKy1kauMG3BFtbmG6iyzELNKC7LL5e8sWviUW@ufIfItkEV03RLjrVjLgWea3mVyXZto15XclcR2pCQkiIQWrUcr9/llaSqo0hoCIobzzIONT7vKLCaNHcqmikzFP@5nWr4JK24/c2KWo1MH47D1BHWoZWE24aq7qIyb2B9ssjwUxBWRwdweLNxox2Dr1NrYiL1u8jSasIaXjdi8rfgHteRJb1xY/o6o0NjodXEwzt5i6hZLgOSO7Qy4BLTRkzKUxtjl5d@gqmKVPLkcAdwvAsMpiDNN@CreRnuBzn9XC8XqB@U/IBoxzjpi7z7AH0nrbtmzx9IV2Z0sHIhn94LX@8lRq1Arl6uu9a4i03Bl34oExqozFun3OzqLYdUc/nBn0eKwEnvcIw4eP3nDG1B5VCfrVYAikxW5Au/LFhXd@KIXqpRd@UdGfdALDZktbIPyoURdoIevA13NiRVvTtyT@DPgYct6vhZ5Jf0y3cps82Xift7u0@Odg4aBztf2Tk43KGSpMivDYrHwzLdlPnn6Ny7L/Fm/YhDnMz7Iw/OcTxxKM4SSuCH7UEQiIcg7rogjr9oQsnm2M2kvrkvPUrPe@q7o3Uuf8TMPBnfk6ax76GJ0BhVlaB/5yyA8/Ow7eeY@OEMJIdUqPXaQ08GHBcqg3smbOacg/snrqTWgKLREoS0bMAjZdANzpEDlNJE9I0ZTppeB1azW5I6tgoarxxCfwnaIQIyAJCPWrfTEgW8NtcqDLwLPCeykdhWjmkLsveDitjnarepWrHN/UIestkb9E8y0nuC0QLi3ODQKmA47XU1xGQUBFWg3gJ6CsSR5h5xh8ooH5SrpUr583NpED5i/4a8FbyBSf4b2nnP2@knxk9KMttXMQAMHmcWs6GLhE1KtKBLjtYUNaiLVbQkK3ozc/J0a3KJfvk3bEGeYkAuW7fyxRiNf7723Nc2s/7MPha@eDOcRAKOWOUo8k1UMZ19fgY7/1esRl7PXOQqK4ovTSeSTSdkQLXXMZ7ILmZJ@xg5j909vrDHqyZ9/eMr7W4ZzijGk6ldK6JoqyPYRJXmw3g0UhP5ekr0EQ36iFr5r00dPr2vCbYAYXeT1Y5fo9eGcUSko5XX0oTXgXquUHE3tfVnkfarek21fVRpH02R9wwv0nDNyeZGVaRpt3n1SkTUwNnShXV8ifylhrk2b1FO5Y3LOKWMLs8OdWfGJWPq73wpmFBaB3kLZIwsDq8VDTEnqdW0SZRwlVpEIV7KUTmFazY/fjG19XAEw8tSciJmXuLLttqLODYYiIrOBrQ9yMXnKIIyvIxNQxmdGjUXaZXJhTZnE6Jf4P@/WFtpEmQDjy@NrH6DRlZfWo18aTXypdXIZVYjCzfLY39Ubnn9MrBmPVE8B@4/swALantPvP/evSNx9N6OePj0wW@Lr@09Fe/fewIpe2L/6f1Huw8E/N95crgjqID@@Yo7QpV7AVO/7bZdup1fqlRWBGGeC1C@Ig6bZ@K9Qdt9CcSz4TfPtk75S6nvBptcauelO5oO@DloiMosgbSaoLsifmtSN05ocd0CSj7Dd0TlyxPbSN48fb5ZItsLCoeuDbj5bY94ENLjomclbbQB8ANIBTRNfpIl3Wl8WiempVMScuD0z2uPIDCFjw/FvSfbGOlze/dod@/JoXi4dwBf97@GbnbE9i66jbn/FLMI8PHe9u7D3Qf3KIEbUCkJvFsjg/XLmlBCcBqV9ovuGMOD9VAqlN8iXr0XMpn@QFlF@CI77ofuezpAUvjuzs5Oa@Si3b517@DdryBX435dWBYGuTQcqksLhFsVNBqB2mQU7Ro7U0fWsljlDelsKm5hdi1Dd0D0uSAU8hy9E3uusB7gNSI@SFPcbGbYFGqo6CbgRlTKEawjKAJDNlvYIJSbUBvdHqja8GK1q75g0S3pmBXlyAXlpdUnpBiccbff5jC6KgHonrW6qdpgxAB4ISQTGADvYDAhaL5wd/GSRKxKiHGAgj8k3OaE52fDh@fINaKBq0y4z4FA1mSbeN5oSjHAUdPr8zxGzJp4d6AYKVTEJ3h0ktPrqStXUokD/l@@seGrLEBasAt2YWUroSJ8dgNqgL39tNkNfGE7ObwNBhHE7XusqXXSa4K4R/fCIzRYeolqBFTtmoM/m8pRvWI4KRCnEmFaUxFthy63LQ9@97rloOT9uRpRb486jQpTMv7TlQ24P9eAN0EDiIrmfoFuhYYBMbaEZtCVpGz7A6BIEPnEx9GoRoPOuO1GCkhZx37uffRRTg5yISxiqPhQ67SGHYZ6wIeQc/RBRW4uQIghTclTfI3iObSjPQjfhs9QGWKEDfxQDa6szRQeVI1SE0dWivx8Sq2tJhnDXVkrUTzrBuvta6h9RtHzt89mefRM0kIxWUtzPvpzRiUG9Ow0QjcvXYGKRdOAWsLBHTLh3vGx8Mv1D9acze37z4off1g4LpdPeFtodvjxgpUS@ZmFRHJYHlp3krQB1UqTSDP@uIWllT4j75a4yhUyYFxOPWC@txo1ncfXqvPpfYqXFU2nxFevHC5VJHsTIiGMJBPubgVRV1UWqMyxyEkE4d4JjUXPuiqlQDj1fr2Fce1xFmowIn3cR0i9xgyrRvo1hrdrfNCDnSUj@TSebo0/p2KRS4qiH9ucj/IH9n0nv5krKyhaTHo4bbVFFxTmak72aobTS@fVHLrty9HB/n19dGuXto6Ph9fCtn0pttdqWzGfjouPJQPX9dF@fAlaPtzeCC30vZCOmA/JeWya0jVxFm4tKJq/osYP5@aO1h6gwbMXI6pqpEZt434PPcTZfCkOTaMCORNNyBAdHm3vHBwIawdv2dahLOx7zX6b7EtxG0TcN5WnI7ZDps2upJkmHSZIM08qZcbmpdFqL1vMiYOXslVIHqQgx0NvFjpqL0gmE2kdwScLsRBoeM0bohq5aOsu1B7k1yXiWR01oUQ4aUYHM4ndXODDh53s0yYTjluBeWP/hTfUzIw7kc666Kp6NDURKUYYj4PmCb58J8/f@8wfr6t6mMFyvz6mDqMSfhv95YtDqHiIL8Wl6AxeMi1qSklnhah0QY0dmeVFOezPTlA6FvtM8sLGti6ZY9k05o9vGZHsiD/dwnf@qcxsn8n7TrXFU8qGOaG58NCzo0cQMJkgBostkyqg@PFMHmE0GvqcdDRDbq61W9SaumolRTOTuGvpQG8BB796O749xKuC3fbSqoqfT1V8SkRqMuJuzdegMgHz7dXV5atwx3uhihc/K24@Q@L7Z3A2fNk0UPpTn1SFgHJ3nxRUfkgAlwydA1Jgx1YLJlYQWJ2EMyXSdzqMzPZBW85HaIsHjdl7elTA@6J4rTkxibUtGTufSCZ2Apnrg7GEdUd51cyN/uzy6u5TULcr6rv5@vXxYkMgvA@f/YrDZB4MhrhVAiM@arBXVBDJ133UiguwBAcf1J5@jRiYWyqOZZ3jzW3xCzfaSHONW8HgBer1q8iZMraZhc9QpbPm8OIVXnC9oitTzkObAFnWK4it56yjwpE1tzoDUiLo6lCWW9zKaBps8y8bZvDNdVQfpDwGMB4wHT2A2bezAuSedbxVUKEms3lOA/5EJxU5CWg1QNlDpy9yOtoleMPeVKeXOb3jYuA5nbohsZw3dcTL7KaEjEfIzFoSmO5qve60QcOus9/hbGBjdNJbsjEgW/YGOvUmp6JOlUqqy7LjMOmYk0CS0kkLEgoPJi8wacl33RcNmmQZbQ4QZgui7/WOS1J/6h1byo45acIR8ERCebffydCkUMxTjUodCVvoWlaSUH3LOy6RAqXcgFAmCyeWF9KWFxYwgSHdCH3JRMXFqAH4WzZCNtUkXqy5vvUcKXzk@u2xK3YmKOOr2IiKKskxyILYebIt9h6Kg739nShqbHEDeRQqpRT2KBSzbBh1Ry3ZAkz4YBycNjhRfY3nnrucq1Dwdw3UH4wMIP4az1UVEIpjXJbi4lXnlajD4T3Uk2J3csdy0lWPdR9K7cG4H1y8mryi6Z0Ap1cCEnhHzEp4SfDO3LDIlSg5bEUO9BaHYSGRr2wotwphLZRCtUykb46BtLiOrfncTGLL6P0Tpg5WJm3SYUBO2CZxJxggy7Mu41vCcLRPw4Cb9JbtCNuONwwPpVJpLjkv7ujAja4ZcTda2TUryadVcjeshClM4yn5GEc0rC0nOgPxynulKgsPFTz61@LSjh5t9N0sp9E4YmjZRWAqx0Y2v0oYfe5kop/mFpycQRGNNypfN3hBYJD3cDd3mMYjYETfc2B6c1BgvIDm4GgVRAB5mcwBUvl5jI3kVoZLL6FIcovD9TjfnJRaQnQJRZJrCRsdnYpwrcdmoz0A7owDkuCHBgiCxvmaOHNANnMVpy1WES8oSZHEmQbXafOfXEIdaptmCKDHY/WxesymNyJrFrsUPjoiZgtk540BwT2I3KngsWamV@Pp5pEkNo3icQijUTFgwBk7qa6eC/YkEkk6R0stXlZktCWjgSOvJY9G2HKODVAioRTQYhSUV00IC6AIQlwcniwGKK/EKGg@GdQgfoI3scbaaqxGDZpPBjXWxxzWYhLWKGg@Djq3r9FGGR17zdAu2pdPXi6FjzXRGVW5E7c9DvikUU4rYA0FsDxMRktCd7wTL3hHhIwWfSpBe5BoV9akR2yVBgL@6h3N@lABxWqbTZDVhghxtzB4KS@hYr6OMtm3kDHXzGMEnkNc4/u4AVonCHMaBHtgkg1RTIYUaNQpplgxc2i41CQQNTJGEpZYuICvM@R@6wsXLO5w5HerYOVmFjerFtlFoU8qWcpHGxtqLErBoOGJxJ@abDzhGAxFFEcpTLrkJ4JjHOhUvOIo9AZtvuwsIK6aEtbqkI4COD3sxHDga8p8X1RBQHN8dTvwQWUeBzYhLy7rlIlDCVXzOBavjUMJbPM4itdvB8lTSX1569o4WBBMwlG@Ng6kwPkxtRYuAMGMf1tJpBYZDzSLkqnNQitKGhpnM/KtFe@LElUF2gsShgj8JPYtqR2SMTdpvWeIQdcaDxQ65sfD9nglbcJRTDt3hS@Yq1gyN7deWLilVL6BNVZeTdzygw4cBKVuT6/vhMUfE9FjlyQSId17oBBTap@OQETC2SxJ6UMxIIQT2t9ooGpWo0E3Q/sHe@8e3HvceHLvMQpRC7xH4fUNasuQuk6ltITx7Pm2pUE6RY5AVQvsRob2YSOP2ifR7NApQpFjsdTChQE3s5iBwpocui8q9d1z8RCyKGj9HE6ELOm7GZgem9qgN3Wr@NLKhZDmCaZ6JeW1TWgJwTCdyJYQjJGcMYQtLv@szxoqz/rPAgZsiTrbZPrHZnufoeGSUVCI4stnwVfcUQt1SYraaSnPIqrgo@xGzqlQ5ULeoIcYjAn8Vbks7iunuNJ@rdlro8vbcZcc3555veZZq9MsDU@Hma7vSPc0drbro5PLDCpT7R7tHBw29jFO184DspzAnxrlHe0@3tl7eoQ5h5C1LJN3Dg72DhqkoH7wdP8IPYbGkiwTUGIJwWRCBOjJ3nv3Hhkw/N2SjWSDEB/kTfgjXfkUhDdsTOj3lMw8CqwK0aAgPGSmgkUprSAC78wdjFXwNvQ/oQ74Alqe4KMM1KWiGpNDGhuvP2Ve6Ot0ZkBRO0bjYUCgpAFvx0YiFy3BMGf@CRYgX0Q@8O2kTV/iG2XMQ0O@wdCOlUUDGSyWkfZdXZ9WBy6Tw2m/bSt00pFn4cLtAyS@NmXHQbe4lp3l0KvkkJSG4oWzZTg5yuQcNZtcUo6g1ErPGEGMzGvXWkYZvAMUWZTQJISWKVSAXxBrIp/3chcZM0CUzIJdleNHXQjDhj4KI@PX3DDmiN2asp4v1I8Eoj9JCxxNI/x133yUIgKT71NkzFFHy3M9ZvRXdZZvmG09Oza9T4V23SXUHnkADb4X2OzohXz2hXQnn7tkAxqYEZ/xaB6gl29jssNUIdO4H9RgoILRVLAFoR/o4YKeH@PviXTt2kYFGhsILmfCWhbnsjtKNBLyAwYgMc/atNZDNzZslqAVhxliw4SoJkF8YEIsJUG8NCGWkyA@/YRBvK6dz6vJ2xRLq6uszRyZz4Ti/6aLF4sKdkOpQoeFAZ9ZXJ3GjGSHcUjovIPmoOaZDcjNlt2@tGVR1J/@O@A2cclSRaqEG35Jsy/B/PPfs9b5hu4ao/TX3ENjg0LmRD55sQkz3hc@kCSumiRtSePYfnIJNstSs5hc9rshRXyQQjSf/jQCk0w231bzLvT4qReuG2HZamjVEEfwH/MInNdB0ODyan2Rt1E24MXspXWNRfUgRMAgyybIUhwkqcpXl1ZZMfFVE6usmiCV61T56c9knfL8SoD4oYagvVYOZiLof0UWGqnmQ6EkUJ8h0aZmP3z1TQU/ibbBLJYEvh9ipyLHl7f759@ItzssmQj/@4nESQVM@lLTnjjw/3BdHMupOD5kFMVi6rhlGSKfT4X49EdhO3h448vsskXy8z@8unQlvfTvhqXDY35THdzMNShk8S1QqwdFM6loXWPj@YMB0CkJrTGOUb3mjCWHZ7E0GIt2oKqzpcVZNHtJZU8Ts5d1dgz5jBksxSWhfz1ijDY4wiCxRuFnsvJlhktlbjom15bjDpncLjPr0sAcxkbzONIUx2B6NmMCx2JEyJhHLXNzktmbZYgLriUKP35z1DztNzFAqz/ol2QEEG9Q3jkbPPfwoBqV0c1F6bmfJg19FtaaEJAc56D4eg8VKqCp0qkI636z3I6AzXZ7fDbu4RuaI@UqdIxULqPLOBIE@@MzX@LEE/f@2OtBDxzk1EIWEcS8IbSSTmFgpa9VfazqpGrnqyyXWW@8RG7oKIna1h55w4Aqc@ZlAXT5RAwqVOFtGLCKhUcD9QtCxK5oHdmfR17ftQ14jOLqFYwE8ouQd7hUjSgjPiYGjgJqgDwZn0UwXMgZJ90Yh3NKPlr82JXCEo6ci3QjRi5GCNHWEZ4vlqQPOnItg0ikBdEoimWpsJLjUSJE@0CeZ1GIlcJSBSsaYha5KCLP0FqzvNklt0Vk1Eo4CJuGplkAjjBEL8d1swK9gwzdLsf65d9@8ndW7qJcVmkUU8frN0FmoIgkIVb8ejTYV98N9CifSFvFGO6/D3Ez6o7b9s6aGKEmMFADcaVghglEzBdAaOi0atCD/WZwYhu@YFSFSFjl8r3tbXH03sHe@2gNxZcIRAWx4kgE68LK87BTyUi@VAxGEEkJ8zCPZcUIpBoxD6V7hWC6x@Rep2sbGlgwWt/8YxotussfoKY7r8sYQsy22KkP3hOibq2JVk@EomCch2/@EWMeDFl7NhnxYGhJwoSPQxeIX11F2nP9Yojk@n7x/T@j6qRFCfB8eK9yZladxvRTbl1eyBLNFqvHqb2KVEODkIr4yiH61o8Jmc9ButVGmLlh7ooaSXK3f/hXgnDg4wPMnlFSRPDkr0T0bUakXw9o5FLxFa/E9x3G1/HoFcBE1JpGu/gYzsnSCI2GbCO5fMXw/eL7ssUA7wX4ZnJJHYuR5mYSJ@NfzZmlsnI60ubXwJ86wz8wkUoz1zSMfFAl4vnkZ@EyNbvJrpOZvm8YqzPWtMQOf/KfSdRHOuawetADOKM1pypxraS0@S/@UuOfZG5MriCYX/7t934U9nGS2rNJan@@F66myXwvJmltvxHbkr6KR4aVn6ROxU@j1URW7sQxvqYh@EnauE@igz1JW/JA@nrRT65Y9mlIvq2Q6AU/uXLJp@H6jsKVuNjj3UpZ7pPUZa6wpyz0GP7FlGbCYvwXczFOLpv51DWfThZ/Q8iR4UPj0blpKZclh1Mh1nZDVOkveubFv5vx1pi7H161hYyLAxwVoEOpKUJ7CDXZMFf@RTym/Iz5mjC1Kp0tqB4ZtVRlLSCaNHt@QlWO87nVtYRDB@JeQi2bb1ZJZlYu9102uh8POyh10PvdGUkeI3r@w@AByTvjN2gugdsGcYWtbcg9QZ2afEwvOP4c@SA68jmkRA30AN0BcYP@bujuFqucQvLGjTiW3oBZoht0nY6iUKogIiWJfPU4UahgOTVxIfyT3oFYumqxdIWDJftIfmTDnCs372/9SO9IepQGUewxlPmrcf6jnAZSMaK3cvLYIXm6dNRO5JsWpKKp6ghIPbr/2dwtYtWl85IGWBrm7/6JPuhcH3VZO9AfNHklj/8YHBMHJvUENPZP/kgI7NxiuGWk1vynauJ93qHSKseT7Br1pFTz4z@wkLSTB4mza1cLWRJjqowldp@Ip4c7B2Lv6dH@0yO8kDEdI2oZPF3QY7Gb92USYKOXBHOybA3E/CUWZ408Ji@v4OWXctT9P/8edp/R5h2rYhnDdGm5H0TKVVW5S8aIpuLaIyTHZ648X1pA67hu2VvHWZMjBAL0bj/A9eq78EGC8cUEO3yWZxuTP5tMm1K3rJjxXGPqP89uGZcx6ZcJeNThBDhVgfPnVL6kjC@GMujKaoqvd07Sax7jh14ol58E@kVTUORmM/nC9/z8vNTF8FTjkVdyfXRP5KNjuPLwBJiF/oAuNdFtNhCe1wbZFp0Xjtsvwk/FdrP/sumjgsw7E1SJdu6@PeW/mbQ74uHJGYfieNN7YiHotrcwLbQLgKzQar8odM87NZnBhsFa4YQTkfsZqS9nvvrkDbsaYhDgPbvOavVetAc94natVg8OMiusmnuoIKfqq/w@9NgwRl0iT6X3U0FMs82KFAIfDSgHPgJXpayLvUl9ehwpPtHFI9osPkfEvBQpKwRjPutxUNiACedPwkpVtfWJdBavTcjw9QGVQhQkopkqmIhFOOZMWCl@E1@oMA0hp5E0tPxpO1RajTd/g3l0FGEATQxhwF27XP/gWf3Zcd93zxeP8@WTAjo6QuiWNGukMSWfPfwZR7/3sjcc@JGkvusHrOBSUUntU0kNTCus@CLHKqZxA83SCjdeOGioHehQJm7R9wLbk2aqpI1zSs/bVt0Kx5gbVpeNwZH2lJKBTMOHJ8PU3kR0bCDCdN0lFYkvSRfKen@E/rQUbBHGHB3A9KdoRoiBGqJLRcYwFbNoq/C1jBNg2NkHbqwrKh@moh7LMro5k/NvNv/maze/C@siufVEsLwpxpTGJi5suK5cLuwRc9Mx5hVaUF5s9tDln7XTJ/c0SnEwV1ssK9MUrge7IIPOGpPflo4n@CW1L7VQsK4pyr5i6vCy5HWhhlRrmoSv8JSvCEGW5w2EI4gkFHNlsYlZDCRd3jjoWSyp2LnRyAk1csJFGHqS0shjWQwDeZpuG47RaVsTziPAV2WNXhILhd98ifGp2BXRYlnXGe45RAXKwhAmFOmsfZxYe91otLFpxRAgIc4h6Ljd5rgXrGfiG161qL/pPYqHUu1R/E2SAe8VQGC0BddYqczWRCZfLPAq3SO3l/CpnrGqhUqhSv8q/N8qqET1vzqfWIlCVqOJlULs368l8RhHNlksqlZWcEPO/GpBDKfB6aC/lFkQ@swWdGajP0J@QX3u8/uw3/eGQzegMEfixO3j4zYGfvUGeGOBzr8wrg58fuGSf5F1hVzwU2zjud9ARA2JqDScCuvWlgXjfjYcjALxUc9rqc8Yo/z2ivrmT310I@W7LvFAPjBB8pkb9X2PRtPdYK@P9xJl9JgcDPhzqzdolc9AlHdH5MrRhzUPEN6gNBr3y@Ruyu138FmczBCaL6Bpp1AddK3TALAGdsvOIeX5LrqntJ5Nul2LnLe4vc6hi4wb3h4JHUllt0N8R9M/tXBbWxBPgAlbZ3cryoeJ9tJFI@6KrHyMK/Y4njNpDGSNSF@o8Y6xLEkzw0KlaPleT67/rBI9QEMpK0dsmZ2jE3EQhPBKlVMWYMWQSAnsIwbpY8YYz4qwRxgi1EXLEtmIvBAygdoRfpWVhglUkTyfvQKwh9grZUXr2jCtzDNW19G9J96VOdWc3ik8tJOqrq1jbA7qCQ4oTpN8Gq6uYQ45qPQFRpxj3zRmP/KObAkA8oRQIETgsUfokaH1nJRI8bIODg@kv5LKw@uJFrpE61GMF7y/6rsnFCVFnLc8DgXT8XwCwJLlk4@8oRyiQoRUW@MTYLVpLVBkFc/3x@7qnbUVahDFNVKgnUE7ArpUBszoWrZMjTsNznq6F3eDU9FzX7o99v/GzabYL7woic5suX3idfPtHJEODGWkpzAK9t0Cp23vPHx072hnuyCK1VUEZwNVDWsbg8vZeconAw5JRliEl2@pdXuFidz2C9mtcjYnm75lDnvebLBCAHvWCOW4oZ11qJi8mWPEIDJ1cK8q6HiLOrYb6mrjcsOmjEcYtcBSg6tW/sKChSSNdS0gCUY2RyiTCw8N@AYbzxxQ6l4BIyB3twYKYRhKiCjX2rhZLOo1tU6firCxFoubbGduPQA5/IXIHoz7kd02S2unKbKwyaG3PN7abmZpXyhZNXHqZN/yszXkzjXn9NIe5y5UiL9@F1th88AdDe5P1fzZY6W1AgOSq1ePczmZkP2f/waxbxaaBfTsIHeB/PVHjnIJW@JNfYc9aNpZvg2GYh@VAncSPKDNNXCCmi7QGnSmJQpJ2nkAZ2/H/sisY2jnLki7ue04y7kLqHI0RDuUIWyG7hFgzNUwrRtJC0WOZ8/66BZ3EeWvrz5@9B5M@QH6l/KD@gfHi7fKhWwWjnjSQHIw0ofY3nu8jzcJo1yJbhQejgZnclxGTV1JCR/20XKYWl@wsGtlXIWwc564gey9f3961Dx50jwDibkJQxC9wGmaWj8Y5h51@c0xcqzo5Fq5ixOHoE5HbrfGnNDMd17aJ7laAH9OzSpWoQpnaYmwB1DIQQcCsVH3@nBav3f0@JGT3WgKxOokrIpsvqWJAwiFCMbGJBJoI6SD4XSRqgK22ySCgZ981tqM9mWj3NzM1maz1PY8GjQ77PErGxJwxx4XJMWNnPkprY1CKpgOXQcT@Gh7d@fIKkBZlH0xkWIcTWnTYmfEjqqDyQ13CjoCp4cI4zgrb79NaVhk7DvOUqWSQ/WQGWAjHxCAlhfWqDYbNZ2OrQeyOfRKdHXuTrguYk6WSkvlZt8/B3a0XL1dubtceWcwwneDjuu33/ZhC3GaGFLWC6ZvoyE/qZOdDHrdt7teDx@sbq4sru1593/nq3cPb2/b7dZvAQ9pPfcH@IA/GpoNGDXPpfYf7LGjNlMXNaIPONvN8rD5YlBe6VTaa5W16p2Oe2fVXassr7VX3eW7rbt377a7K2utzt07zTur7VYZ3UZTkdIZKQ9aTP5Ybfd61aYxZmtLlbvdbrV6@05n9W737lJleXmltbbaqaysdNeqzeXl252ltdbd1uVcW9ieDGywat/FsyO@A7@Vztxl5vZ2WTr3vw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xos4721en _e25 $91 <>60or 70939597cr=B+Ru8"?!"&&1/<>ca ge 8 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201 )#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

In Seriously `.` is printing command and `[...]` is a list literal, so hiding dots inside square brackets works for both brainfuck and Seriously.
The only problem is `'[` on the first line, which is character literal in Seriously. It is there for 05AB1E. It is solved by placing 05AB1E code `26q` before `[]`:

```
ef26q-[af.q]
```

`e` is for CSL, first `f` is for evil. Also `ef` skips first `q` in Beatnik. `.q` is Pyth exit command. `af` is used to skip second `q` in Beatnik.
`[k.q]` would also work, but it triggers some behavior that doesn't work in alphuck abstraction, but works in real alphuck interpreter.

Seriously code is after x86:

```
1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss
```

`1` is for Whirl. `]'[` closes `[` for Seriously, but not brainfuck. `kX` clears stack. `"204".` prints 204. `â` exits Seriously: `\xC3` does nothing, `\xA2`
exits if stack is empty – see [commands](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/v1/commands.txt). Second `'` is for Shove, `PPQ` is for Trigger.

Slightly changed x86 to get rid of `Q` for Trigger.

Polyglot is passed unmodified to Seriously, which treats it as cp437-encoded. So polyglot will not work in Seriously TIO [wrapper](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/seriously) which converts Unicode to cp437.

Answer (score 6):

## 210. Haskell without MonomorphismRestriction, <s>10035</s> 9977 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLfFjF8kiWVKxil1VlEip9eHMeDHr4/GDPZ4djD1rnzPjXew8GNjBYh9seBYLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zzq4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRmRt2oodvfXvw7ihx2a@qijmw5zVNthLUu7Vq0EWx@xF4pmZ9OZQAChqlZn0FMNxy4GgkxmTDOaWgv8zDGvVEO7VS0ITzPWt8yOpfSY01UcptpNpa/azBw4/YHDzPb8ZBnGtnrmpRbHlD3N6ACYo1p9S3UofoWxU0NXeo2WMhWTncqwb0G8zTZV/Uvvi8OaZq@nGC0bIHOMvTEtW0X4pmrbJiZfZWy4pTankOYBVLE0c6@6/3IqqsDYSyii0tfVIVMatmMpTUczDaRJih3vnx4fTqWQZfbuZHt7OjTNXsdNg20PmlfTURl2atmKrkzjX2HVgWPuOtPhWVbtqIbC0olCIj0dmWPrljKTZJVZqtJqa7qagAZhcdZV9b5qMQxhbdNiu1AkPZ/Kp@rVccpEE9Pmx5HTaAtMz2ScqfqkU0B40@qqBpQwNR0pe5FTEWkvoqVRBoo1YmG7a1rARxYb2GqL3ZhWC5jL0EeRGKRnw1vWUGw1t4IIMh6CK8O8MYCJHBOatjFyVGaYRpwSI@AKk/fq04yVzmJo9WB3OjzH0nvTYavAaM2r9mxbpvPsyOyPpkML7I22N4@dMyneETbMFrTGVJzMDhUIomwmCZ9JT/aCJrQudGZ2aUPBWiqzDa3fVx0eCbyiWhQNqZmuGVe8gx9aZmvQxM7ndFXIGzss8oMdaEKqCusLMZFABwsSB3EwKMGx2VP95bWZoUID2X21qbW1Jmcsdeiohg1FthNMg0rcaLrOWqoOCcbYmzFmm9i846CGrnQTzUQAGRNzYb0rnWms2e8zHgW1gCJtp/JMReqxW4jXuzYb9nvM1noQ7TTNdltV2a3a70LyQMsMMPg0@1PV8nxLKsAYqksatQ8CAUljIqWBTi6FbiwFSGvZggaO1gPCak7IZqpiayhQIYmtGi2iat8TtSZTJlieXWvQ4aHqA4tw26pFXY7wQve0VECpeM0cvrE0x6Few6rsUFUsdmKpamRS7E5kCZmZmIODFUlQo66thbYOtkPQuDxFQulDY1qZk7evAgpLlNlSvQTfsiSVAlv7m@xu6QLdXMoCA/StsBJh5R@Ynby4UOE7lBvJjnUfAKwBoIrOkmbfSSrxPhQw7kABkwo60RW/Tif6ui9jtjbVFj6W41AtaA0QPuxdjGrWHFgWjiRjoipXUGndNDpAT6isNTCQHgbLpaAJmiYMBDGmXgPVQPJSG4FcQAqfdDVoNBubxNex@HhIBIUREdhYUNTN1zb1AcFBSttBXgaqQFLEuNtm71hb0XRMAvGIipfaUu2B7mCagdHClofxTm0lmFsM6rAW8PE1ZKcAUgoA1u/5@iUVCoChIUyqKkb9@E//rNXpAJ5qswmyTbDrO9YymzRyK1RYGA4ZMiwIVJ2KBXAxzJ0nhwyuFV1rkYBQjJHIggpBud6YA73FTMjQutGgl3aVa@jZ0LmajsqZnA/2MdZTrrg00TjnQsV7SgMaljKgvKnacfZiA1qpqQaCxDPx3sBp51m8v8VCdvL78PNi@PnihQqFiyQiy0vJZKcEDJdYpiDwhR7jnHfVCUlpO4ptaq1Af@R0TSPN4k0mNctmXzXCoQkcoVjIaoQiCZRy4UhJKzcTbc1ohUNrwIsVyDgUKTXLzXOtWCtNJfdnCWhuEA12VzXcjEgBEDnUKa6TPZDmCRgc3sWFyxdn2nUkOUYnfMFImOmwax4QJGUH@dJEBgE5lLB1Ve2HUwk5gmIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwUatFQ8FQ1F91wgA1nagodtYTzUSxpfe7OGgBUQy7DyOBhbzbhJEaJaOtOaBxxliD@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@6zpO3y7COKE53UEjAZySPLFGu86BgcySdKyR5pjc3dDNBohlG/pn0s0h2Rw0tOFUhSjMa8NLO3ANCljbZmUYuT8PgOvCobYNApPCNxDYFyWR4CYU/FcCQAJKAKHCbZtE8TYIleOR0QxLCepKCeh0UoxJ2HElMHckTOXRZcPsoRRiZ6QYoKYHZp9moK0gZD6JfGXuUOfJftLrQqHEpakZ4bvQ4uJiqBiqgGRfXHwOrjV0PUdXFFzPyRUnF8Il0EUpYuTC2HNKgWG10P25i3kYqWGzDXFUutX6YeW8WMzUYsq5LJ5pfEZA1IFkA@g4PgBPKFIuozMSkSo3UNFEoz1Z@w2UzsdNS@sLIrxSrhXuF1TIEBm0Xh/NSEst4SD7OE16ZQtGQVBam92wFbo4T13ULu4uWtGL@1AMU0dKSrkBlYL8wr1ExzIHMFxGzleKcbkWiZxnYJBslEOp0HI4nI/rkJESiXyXj0QVTu1wSAWpHb64CAFRBX3Om12L8A1j6UjEIxWUAwdm0AnDocRdHvJvRGqRaAjSRkIxMDHKoRBQpolEsKnSyJkTBDo4es0JsxGNBogNTesKvzNiH8ISYGDx5NvAvxvHk2Zv7wqkK2vaOqoicYtrI@BNLvPAFj08javIdkljNWC4hRrAaNvyLCO0xo0B6c@k3Jr@jMgcRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOI29oQDATo9yNXEcLxG3WhDTA4TV1NnJFqIjHoOGj2qom52tAhH1YSTXvMA6D3gLOvK03o2JPoLiR2AQiBz5PJ@TGR0gziaVWJrJqv1REGlqZiIP1aGmntA83uInlBs0JTwmoDVVFlB91AJartsiaM@R2gtDrUHK7DAx8dY5IdxQ5HUGuscq0LlT3UGLBQ7hwADedmE@wdFTQHjOXGI9syrjXLNJDIiS1ADQxfwjaYQj6PvMBG1epuevNh@s5DDhSbCZZ9tPVjnSZu026ypGHqZsdkywCArJlIcMbeNXCqBHQ@B8xLZmu3RKBqxzRGUzyo4nBvo44o5zKe9q0gZJLgE5cga9j8So8BHqjz8e7HLRgh5GwqBeV3fSn6eJX0YZmuIwY22RhATNnqyDfYkh/Vfnc0MaGE/MGtSOAnU@Udk9v1CgyoUCrRw28pqb@T8xDo525Uy3XNq/sWaUg4leG3MiZqD8og9FNRHd5toIbBqWAMdUkxgXSmwcfti4LrIjkhtzzDKd7umY6SfJfo2gx/AqgvxDUm2cnQYigZj@OvRFEsXWHJlnqdRCklMINUPukO1IDa7JpMugDdxQ8kgQjtghIeh0qoFql5XjIxOR1wzAHoiy1V13qas0sTabqBStF4wHdjcT5wjOBQU52AsGTGghsnu8ZS3Ohw@K0hDnV2QKUn2z/Y3KofVk92ylJyYFtJXWtA32ip9R6otLpqS2z6E2RHKiAT6W@v9CPTdMqcEa509tVPENO4yfc263u760fVow@8EITG1noDXcGiFJemADD5MUW7/dU3w9i2zJ6n69uiIZYySHp1YjUBDV8Ru4KxA7GW4AvPYXgP1wcSzUCn2WRxk3u9QAG4ioC4ZkCjYycaRUhaQ/ACBWSeUOI6QsJquIEFDPRWECbm1sfo5sU/nEhgvpNT94jcNgZ231ezO1mm8Gun3UZ9wAtOU/BVHDuRPg7OUDBfgZic@xdkmYmaC@zhWyF8fOViLr6ZqLnAHr4sx4crHvPRTcXMA/WQ5QgZrpDMxTUVMQfQw7RKmPyrKuO4PMU9tKQi8pob/WAiD3eBcOOyyxgVLcKIIBcwzbmjx5dE7DrOvo55JC1PxGIUX0hh8RaYPWsIgvzyBZdYIAj0Q7vfSjhDZ4wi40cRB22GL7B48ZwRZL2u1KFXjkvrhviiWFwHASbnxomzXmJzKqmpjYM9cN6uab0OImDg69JuiD/KS8Sb0F3J8XeKNG9By@yPfH35Ls2J39OEOPH1rgwnN8kh1LusiUhO7b67mjMRx7slX8GpX/JpwLpYwMF24YLwBAb1PRNUsT3NpnVVv2QMeCbDRUBy7Z4JBV8ax6TH848sfj1/4lTyIyKZDWL1ykRze@yqpxJyFrF4KHpX@mzKNmit9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvQabfqZA1AUc3IwLOIiE1LlFa4r4LShCTaEekNgNLtAyIBamqEkj@iB8wzzyjM5YzJRmIbaHoB6nQTzD91fAYsX8gTZbjS0h0CBLlh09zm3kkcDMHHSiZWE7NpTOEMJNhWf7jjZPSBA6L/dmWk2NtEUzsByIJV4/qeftaBJZhusq4zIyPAcdaAkcUv7wfYTSdFDP/PbmmAuB7qmEGHI9TWUTQVXNhTdc8xHjToNi8e7itVDXV40N7Ar/kB/e4TzeMktVR@0VPc5P5MiIyJPTucxQ@ux5hxogp2aeeSZkfWmm0qLyMBtLE2lRBY2Nm8GdcitDZ8yC8LooYzmTBCy8Yqc0x04A/6Li3Bfa0atj9@HiDABm8oqDVlNmrbS0NRHmt1SrgYtM96/6lClsWi5ObDj@jdwPive1pUr7qyjcz4BeBUtrdNRLff5ENhNF8wGsneSN/R4hDNc1YqRsqw8htPS@e9DIO42GM/xMJ00nX6e0NAeQxGLNKGTIGlxpT3uI5M2RVhdaYzQ7ut@O2dhhqSzgpwpN6PRVAYHWW9ZZbym3@8/nB5HZkpfKMxPzdf4OUnm2SxJvrYf53NeVGex2v@VTg5Dl9ZT9Hi65XM@KMXd@dSxaw4oTQLEm7piAzM5ojnUa2g@@nmMwXE0aiJbjV2PsPe4OO7q2kMLNaKXip7cNHXNxu6sPyQ1p@e2x3niLgv6GSdF3yxhW6QG292455ovCcymg6skDzDaEyQbX6DAJSAf5yTMh4jWNG/w@6By0TWvVf47f3C7nVuqJ8iouE4soTXnCtBW82uciivt9DOfjldzy@U09bnhYj1g0hR4Ki/bmm7aYJPj72OkAO3atvnvfC72U01TjDhNW/vd85OJQvVZQkzTPdCWit4x9Vy@k1Tg58EGH1htlPzi@VSJ50ksWf66xHL1INOQxfNBUX@VtK6@xgk0t23hGpjP@cg4O09sibWThysI9gMubM@v3HYqTykTST5B8lADWM3ujTJynz9hNHmIuu5o0h@RXg1qHiYo5MHhWFzX/im5rTyeW@tpImkG7erXKuFr3CtdhcGLfmealKVT8jemkFOppwuotj5QB@pc@XTQuFRxa@Mj1sbTC5US1VgSU4lJIB5OJHpQt8JqfFKpcdxG36MCRtE16ORf1W7myrs@6OJ9NLQPwXGIjtmEHWPQn2jcCWvNOHqcct2@27PN1kQhMeZbJVL@6zrUhLpuq/R9SLXf6plgG5s9UBuMJ7S/QEqzHvx3AjGFjBWNicmRudl7C@Wgy4LqAS2qXdlxnBd/mtBJP2TQE3ChkDQ0Q3VG@PsQpecJ0YZp6t/SMiBLWxptYdbjuGn1ay00o@aIPRNsPHVh4zRIo/3QpAUfZ4RxCdRDu9l5xFL2T0U9Yg3OTKs/Mlr5Jtm/Zl/CSE2zQrbVdN0PMSRNfsiJfGL1UXbkWqjZUHWFP4a5lcfwFRKZR/F5WodQb2lRBhdy@NLNeFUtOCV6@iMgltYC26Sr9lTyPqLUK63Lge0@HgQamvidE51I0kLEA@n6GvR1A38nlol82pBjGmBNOYrVUdEc0XFlVIQ@JF/d9Y25xN3tKR2Vn3B4THSMZyVwMx034sbO@fMTRb6/pQnJ@PL/46wAHedKHdnucy7CN6MmtOeg9/VZtak@3sTZz6926kRy7rLOV9Q9o2t2ja7atahzeL6HugdwpMPPpjxWCSh/V7GvcPcgyaOxNde1/dTVTV1/CnVRHnLpaJrzJ2a3cOd/C5J@E96R0oAI8fjqjB0M2UQkGrsf6jtddQAjk206Zl@Nk@8hUB0ne/jv/Lnm3YOQzc401WrxrQ@gjkPWWkNX2Y0GRbi0/evO8yeSGrqp4AbVR5R3oIz7fMrUVNO0vjrv0VFMp9@nR72vD2z6oRndOJ3TmFfdbSrpU5hBc/iuE86yasdsNLva14rUUBXH0K6S7hwO9z5qlwphTDXXWHwTgxO6BrSyRglkgrI//hgfuw@Nf74lnLm13xhY1ujrgmFyxd@bauUrBOh4KH@xODsnmoZ83Fblbh96ZJlCrOU@yE2kQKOyHFdToJXID84ATewgE9KLFhUfUHqm6k2F8a2jfcvUpdgMQJN4mm9DA4TPm7x4SBDuCPkGVmF4Z9CxI19n3G4LdCr8mYuw2sHDWnwlydbNG99EM3R9xRCPuaOyt@r42BJI9tE1kERSrHXG1cGDs1u61rf5L4u303OxzC7ez0KN5lu6onlaapsvU6Dra5pdz7RwGz2oEPGmpdpNnPFG6culIhc5htkBKRzX2RjYhZ1bhdn9AvN0k8kRLv5@X@0ouK1uT8Mddro9O@gB5umtA09B/Hag2Nrbgemoc3FObyF4Cso3Skdr7ky0govQpa7Yg8UfE50Ag2Yb4qar2bSb2XXM7ziczWg1fjZyelLdO1X3@ESITy8Sm0pZfJe5m089B07rY7wyN69JrVMsxD8o6DSHJkzFc24952@3eGwW4WbQ6w9s8Zifew/PJvhnjntXFG7faCAF459B6LKuojvzZ5d9k6egT4mRcOx8SMv@qOlmh33MpxioXyDgUOl@gLHWYVw@VBzoAcYcZqX8n7huiXMTca7U2J@BEdQMi2uG5jw@D@M4CthB7hMrxFUtPHuT3MPfxItvxRA/mU@VvUclPgzpo6YOls3XoA4/fAVC3fj60PKVZRcYKk1j4MTxvOJjQ0Tu0SGiyIb5nI8HWPjt1pvTiMsKnW6T72X8iiZmq2DRDWx9NHY9uNg/h8M0PKf9sJCdTeGaBptqWxnozhGu6D0lXbXf13FmA2T6pjnPhDkcwRDzTXYQjBKD3qbaxJXAJ5Vh33wD6hmMW32Qqr0jFZfupwSJSMx37RzRgVTv6JIdEztuIUyzxLlJO@EeTg7S7mQ6yOQebGFBPF41QBXJMa0EI7hwWIlGI5EAT4TLTB0DwFwoOh6KR8f4yVObASc6BKu12fk5W7obFlNF@Z6VmVSUWK3GseKHDjJtDft0tvOIJz9fUmrlpVA8HloKXRhFlgp54KoOwnYuuDIB29bowcs7JgEzFL4HHd1ujUv8aJzdpWOnYFi0wEA5NWjeEI0dfsCLnx48wX0sf/OXLXEat6NCZXsaKDxAEDyMbvbUrnnznOcrcgc2UvA0L@KAsVHnZ8viG1UGQhssGX4I17xhp9sneXG0T5x8B88h13S9UvDGxbk03Jjv8MbjpfE2WYuMvVRupUBEDHoG2I4tp2sn2LFGe@4H1niLK7gQzHAsNKBbMbbLWipuH6CjFDRnpJvmFZ2JwpL8zV/yA410oEJsdHezp4PMvhzx3IRMpwibTXMApXaR3KqWKUDCSGQYKQc4G8tQeFJ4BI8Z0ElL4Mi4e86QsuGHDTeqxyy@xUJ4qB@PL5W0dnipevTy3XmqVv6B9ZLqf/pZMnInCCd9Fy/kbCnGXJDSPTKWPzoL0ePYEJOWhhLP0Dttoomuf8PbA0ikcCbDAycuj5lmX/QaOitOR6M9bhR3loTRTe3sHjjs0TFzYlj1hg4c0l5sAzs@nt82bOhg4I0Qat7rykvhAZ80jB87LAsZ4qFNBVz8YDqdv8DDc5hkaci@sC4yWbyJZwLAxwmp43nNXnnd3VCW8W/7S26qjQFtdblOJ9KZMlVnqV5eq5DLUlsmnps@//5imE7FL4arW7Wk7RL14mL4XSr9HqhuWpDqWRJ73tb@5t1SopL68sVWRkyS7kMlvk0RxMTS3eHu4dbxSfXk9Bha4d4VP9um1VPGsga5iHb5d02dTqQDXSxNtb9B/ng@AA@H2ZLC1vCulUgk4N9mTqCC1lJcWuJOn2iaSP2V5PPS26ovfhZAyLS2xlyO2oUhB9sQmA2phpUf9PFcPRNpxdlg4jINZTx2II8wuBl0jiwlUkmsDMSKA7GeSCr2cGWf87CnUOyrWB4n2/O5IEgxL79zL55XcS4J7n8r9e7DQPmb15tjebzeBPNIvQHUC3XTbFd3906PtiaTAY/Rk6RuuZAV5yu4cMaexucb3cPQdMhNJMQJ17LEJErAvWIwo4t0Gqpzo0K1hHBs9nhi4lAqvxQYMyZQpoy3EdVKnBbhMJUAdZASVmvq@EdbG/qK6I7RPnR3vIqeENiWPNRuwROSwBykm2ES@HGrgVgFudyud0hCXMjrkO1Xf2Juj8Oq4RgNthylemCo8kYdm8G/b1RyXekaGzIxnMk1Fmdp@Oqq0YEKu7CREh@j2BInhLTEyy555cVbSaBMrUuF5j1oJ6I44QKjtK708QoEAb1vOmqRfR6YdFDPFSaefnGDVrXCL@Chpm0qWBs6AGg4eJ2BO24Rvt3t4zJqZ1w1I/nu57mBgQMVAPmuwwGV3cKbi9ok6/nFGpzkprjDwR0qaSLcFme2PS3BZteaTRPl2Aht1HF0kJRYG1FxvIuKjmiyqm6DTtKC4Zvf3ETKSYK2y/M983GDSUHgyYSnMsaYFEBYuzx7ph@G0psmDKufeOIlgiPMtg9naG0xHgfKdTTDvTupiPP5NNFZZI41wF0nldBMErcIRXLFu05P9wHOud3kQk3@@E//jN9ocuGA@@fCPUytg@8Pha8N7n/ixsgy@P6Z50uD74@47/skNtnsNQ4ie2HmPXi2APjyhTRTJ5QJ7gVSVBevtbGl3@0eMpsWHbAte8rQ10woYZDnNAPopfWAKa6pjRGc5zBuwjGe8Pk7YBHgK@APVG9Qo6H8VKsWxsP8xWQSC44zIwnakK4O@YoDne3/PMA7bUAJS@ayuRU5CYWMX7sI6YBtB7dEc4SRSBFkYuBa65c/NZp40oVJdlPR1XKuxHkjuaR8n5E@eQVdAtgANxTOGaTBwzFeCoiriGThJSUqRzApDmQhOYQyrWVyVgNtMEwOAIlgsOGeIwR10xSkAj421KFDGtPINYAaeHcZzpSq/GYjF1EcEHHcePPKdHccb3LGQyG@DprwN4N0hmDHCFaU5jHr@ffswrkwauIGHgaM98s5rGuA@x/PuZaHcxYeOZ69DyY8fZsL1oa9ODZM3Ay/DaVl4XQynUnKuYiPQyWBCsqLXf0LoITODcKiqWqXZt@ubmztvjo4PJ6514QgQ9NgIRaqrEUv4onYec1zhLxyTxJ1fTt5/GZ92yWlv1Tj/SIIMd40Ml3MeblNl/SB3M/47vLZvCliJiM59VTEtEIb36Y9VbPYx7FJH@AG39w6k2s4cnd/XlurXBjBmey/zLvrKZhYRuYC14VNNz2FpouJRdx198yf4B2SdsI9PJWWxjeZeUe@uH8c/PDNJN6NlOPrSdzd@QE63js@Apx4YN8@1D2R5FnR3Ry8YG55Qda4RZWxqOMMm4GZPT/@0jBRl9nLM8X5NY9IB3wOyb360OaQNglnPstEdwR5NPPgTlyM2PXHF4aImzK6UDpdawRuxKFu9/Sfd6A7Yfd1zQlHAoaAmD4HOAtpP3rvhgemlM@HzDvQZqPOOEzQjHGYrrW6qQX4tSXMvV0kSheUHA6Abodmn41n0TZV13UEOhXbHPAZRJW9GvQArk2PIxVHCxW0rDgkBnqG3KKc45UcghKJXisbHkYSXXXY0jow4oQjMRBN38ny@GoTBe/mAL2qMa8GOC3V7ypQB2yazBreDDKMrBXIO64gn7tkN/ODjVoAkGHSRqTIZy5Cp4Z7CxU2fJGFYh5lGpFYKMG4JSUumKJ9CzQRlWAbXdzlSVMf7bZGKpv/wgA@mLc1q5fAWsEww1noJe7x9nPNN90y46OMcq4kNKOlDsN4oL9YQzpBeOjm7DoUkWZYnK66ERebtKbvvHFloeIIoTS@L2ZK3hUKnpybFA2FAl4KgEcjwSiBHI8daw@coCKE2z2lz8IDujTIZglG3vBF2IjZjhVh8QoO1zfMYNEozWnAgyLAZkHQNrk0up0hjHfshZNlaCQMtY0WPm61PjuXE4kauCmTCFvC@cwN0KZwJjASABsVkhQJLegX8FfEEvEbURPiZtQlyjZA93YA1NxoklO4OADyBWhBtWaVZ777DsYChlO1UCiK1piU9gUGfLE2RyAC2jlS3LURgL7ibBtQDWU0QG1YaksDefnitWoYKhAIeKaHF8AqA2AyKxJz7yaOje8OpByCvIg74rAcFHTyTsGt0J1ugrq2lCzR1FjpHtSaTxeo17SFZjNK/rfJRLJ0F17Sy6Mk6JqRSnipW5ajmeVodMlYDi8ZqG09e4YzavdLoMzVE2CgDgEovqRHSsDPoPyVl4zSkrIWXmqV08uUArxgIt9Bgh/sZOJuSblPLj0DZSkGIRYXOuElm677SSUS8j2UD3vIUjIGPHOH99bQjcOY/ZIWjWIZEkt1LMAPyYvjKA2bF8dJmrwrCVsg2emJ7jalinktMXNTMiegCC56A1YWByyx8bHuAo9vFMzMi3tA/eMZv8bt4Yx2tai23/iSJmOeLliEnEaZK4RMmN@3BAQchoGI6I0pkQgIk1//OijnGJOe5zJhM/o8mypFQ1kZzHSwr4MvQA9PLkuWdHexGb9majud@xw/V9qJz7XDq8PD95GLMCuwUHDjQJJXpO/xUuinfVZZ@oEP@@mfYHA5GQgml@Vnq8nkp0@fwOKAz3klUQHxwT@R83iodh5eZayyurocy@WXYy9CdV@xIuF0OnLMNC3JLrS@3WrB1@zS9eDhIP88f055gfkP/4yHifyFw/UgiAgNfiPctZINsotVRVmOrqRfGKVEOpX@m3@3eB@7O6yv/c3v9ZLqIj4O8PHz@zfoPpaz3y0ufre@vrISA0Jy9@HHww/VanVlM5Y9PM8@X4mnFtf@4/@xuJhOr6WTizXblmuh86v3Ujq1IiX@5i9Ch4dv67YNhCjgJ8NkcOJvHr4yy2bZFbuFz1Wb4T@5b1s@t4LuRvsW71gCe6VMwiYUymZCx9@H5jfbIpMrz1f/8x8ffA46wUo6eWbB0wl@DubyQe4EB/gyru86WAmuIVjuPjhKlstlcK7@5/8V0ldeAR6MGa3BTyXr4sqNgpV4mZJ8CVZy4JDTacj3//rZzwLByjB4G5RlOTiivzq64ZN/Jj9j6EhKq3nJNF/gBeb4Gfo@41okZTl94banr7mxab3gLuCGdmWmL8xrd4@rmOAGcjwVrgI/W/j52//9b//0b/@Y/v6Uvv8B78XOLb74tMmYCiMwforFFzPtsDflP0rE4ZPwekcQvXFRs2C@HKvzUnksHPQ5pujg/TJBEs//jXCBoHu5K8qh2kRjXATl/MrBi@GTP2xcaJe2wTFJvczZdJjbGJ6HubKAfQtcIPhDuXzk4N@bBv4d2vjHhj/lg@zwHD6L8Ef/8PG8@LtIISKYQGY/i7@B9A0Ez4PntdqOgX@fu/Rn4V/jM/7t3eLfZwf/Tpr4d/QZ/05u8Y/N1CYQXFtbC0ajR6AyCqZ9yucUvolEXfg85g0Ggr/VD1s5yB28CECfqEXj9/fnie@H0VJJ/IMyVfJ8@OEuKFbtPh5f@74SjZ5T8c4ropxr8VoFysqLTD/frwHi6Nr52lqiXqlU4rXvK@drk4lEuhcvothRX0DCSu38PBC8w7Yo488y/jRt/E1LUpK8X1Cuw0BdCARRxy1wVbcgAhi92QH9geCntU/h6PPo85Seuk7JV/LVG/Ng/H9wMIQIbZi6NK1UN9WVWyAqWUo9TY1So2GqZx7ILXCq8JfqgVNLtYepTspIGbI8Gk6gevi/d2A6bw5MwGZCSmeYchBxqg3PzsHBG8DXhrwv4U9LpVJDKOQwdQ3/KR0FN10aR8/v65GLwDmTPqmgFiTkUCIVSuRCIa2WzfU/S7FQ/eI8VCsFk/bFRZIrTCy9UqLLAu/v6/Wt/c16PYkstLYUfRGNv4BPuRJdE4/nwUrp@UUxjk3HWS9RDybXnl9UMnF056LQPmkIW0tGv/EzRgnPyuJFAGzAszP8nt1c33AXOch1cXbmxeJPEoPIRUHwAdDk3PQTDgbK5@/ov3XwX9b/m1MWPq9FGAvf3a@F6RPBv0jk7v7uXvxWIuGw8ITX4A8DwI9J7u4r6CSgO3CdhyO1yP09D4PfcGSNI6xgHmsVSjwGhL4a5LlehEqMgbEUFutsFxfDVCpSakCIN@OufKElm0iJNrMsNXCZDQwEeTlCINmVUmlFuFfzpVJeuOVcrlRa9qBS4BFOAFJtpVlCRi8F@xEsA2f/cArnWehG1lC4pbbxav7n/T4Ye3Ih9eWLF1SvtzSrXsfwzJcvF9CTQriXpVzIQkgq/@ULdL9QBAzBfVOsohbArJOT6TH6rmIrjmOFwdSPXYRww5x9EYpgfDqVQmBMz7Jra7mVSiW3Au5cPhIpSUt8I0y4Ey3IkfulpMSrASZaKCii5PxqhELvQxjPgmvseQU43MYPu7sPErXZSjYSbozUiBcgFwo8hK3kwvloQfyVFyNsLVlZZuLv/DwTXVleXX5Rq42HLhQTpTulLN@X75Qizhvcl5riPlTcn6o8e5YpAF3yqdJFoF7frJ5U6/hiCVyTBunLMJAETgDXG/tW6JwmebKF2jnWpHYRChVLL3jD5rMsGCoJuHgIRBfLF6jCQbAktTZuTB8SVv4tysvpzGIyO/wut5UCzfvLMn7Oz8/z6Xx0GUTbcqFQq9Uo9MsipTnvDds1uherHD@Xc9laHHWXy2F7Odhn8momuBzo0@6i1RRr4QKthZNmixAI7coauJZuq7ruXkF7Y1p660ZrqYD9cK@6sXUSS68ByvR2dSOWPj5dD8rozY79FJ1B/9FWdfPgFBIc7m1Vj7de7r7bOj2EcBsGSCAWfHqHijpQ6@rNYHCD/rpKnw3NVi4vlX6/3ofPsP3jL//gx1/@dz/@@R/9@Od/8OOf/@mvfvGnfwDfv4TvH/HnH/3bQhZ/f/WLf/Y///iv/xwC/wN8/z18/92vfvEvfsa/5P9r@P6fvrC/Fl8fHP8CKQHbH/7qF3/8F7/6xT/5l/D9V@L7L6e/P/7J/8b//6P4Q@ef//gnf40/wvMHf/Tj7//xj7//ez/@/s9//P1/CMj//q9@if9//Fd//@9/if//y7/5@7/6H/7@D/8ncvwZd/zf/@rf8t@/@70/@Lvf/@d/93u/eOD3Dx79/cUTwn/xOwh5ejmfgucp9frWkF/8pPL8JtQY50IM9qf/@Md/8Y@Ac/@E@/578MG/F/Vzz@PFRMmqi0fHgT9n7EsS9KbUiy8eKKD8HzEUgtmXSWwUmnJDf/WLf/4XGDwB@4/8GFLyLOwSAnu5/Rxg/7VXMD/sz3/85c9@/It/@OMv/@zHX/4hCrT4SiFWjcXlr0wMAWD2CXAImHsKHADKa7hGvsgWA2lwLK7hREZAjn76BCRdBBco4MuBbAZ8aMhMf2q1Cn4uzpOVi@RFhX9q4E8kKxiSSF4kMT6RRJVerhAyKFU0ADmDQbTMZyKiOAEB32FgpQA@nJuIwhAU5VFRiFqPsnK5HA0MyxBHoODFNENWyaPVhUZHGfBiIp4mVs@DVsuG64QFUpajR6y@XB7yhFEMqBAGhgXCoCNJTkvRfHkTMiwPNxniQuTRwCd4fipX8uVhBdH9QEUAHNF1yBKgyli6YeUH8JcJJ8AHhps/QFHy5Wi0koeQMlWVcovVKU85S5WjukcZ1RvDwQKGx/MXjH0nyXmJG3/QFkxA4290DP2c5kCeQ/xFdFlUh/5dJ32XMT009JDow8N4/HMMpvQCAPDG47ghC77xOJbmBUQPOaooZQuPKMcAlIuKOSQvgIbpaCBK7RslD@QPZXjaZ63i8yA6rM7S0hK41ipSRjoAU4JZV0XbUSxcryAlqcikXEHCYNzfoi4dkrGxvLkMvzL8by3SHlVOjuXAUgh1gRBz84hHM@aKGaTSu1WjuixTyaMEFwiOw7mCS4tOoJmusEggTJeyR8hYVft9eL6xO@vmEJTQmCTF5ByfVo4IW/aDWSyWf5BXVgPwJP8A74MXN5NDM@A7whLYy5Cglbs49Th0gr6SC1QqYuGMyYHK8dYJJDg5YHI6lWCgud6trKZXsivZdCaXy66m5ZVcYSWXzWdAxOVS2XRaLqysFPKF1Xsq0gsQFbHiciO7VvkHM5//5h/M@8wPxU@g8p4NEyx@H6gM4/FkmkpclrOrpVEZykFBgQppYlxHH93Fcb9k4IL2Z93hViAoVuAujmy6AB8WWAiwBQiCD6DFJQMm1rF3D0piQQ/ftMEX9SQ5C4wQCVwAI3Bsgf7EJ4Ct9gxEzTOZO7O5sTOFzhM897UPGUAbGGwPd046Jjsx@Q69dbUZWBMnliqBAC1/nANFawG8x/68FlhLerHzMW10@dvnNiwTFNyfDrOuGFc8alPjZ1W8qB0FL5Oye5rTfQDitN/DUzSq9TvDsNVrQAFxmpMDrMOPpZvmPIBVdnr4QC3feOdIcR2RDpIC@NHuy50T3/Nkq7qxE8ix9YP9zalHVgBl2d7W9onnXeWxbtKsh@LD1t7etFc80EhZZNnVWAyEI/zgM0YfeiaWvndB5MTDw24qBlZUXT3mb18w7ZVVYOmyXAqypXS2IBcyhdXyevSoPshLzxelDNigTYV1ClkgkjEYttOpYi41sBxthUylwBvcPlaQ@TEIzQ7sgB3Tw7vo8R4DJ2CpLbBpbgw64dHAN0oN@uzBQHhgEDotrdMF@XZjugCBhqIw@H7rB9Kr/o/zeIDD86CwmRh9DjgumGltlgokaM4rXchn84VMOh/LF/IrWTD3sjE5HZNX86uFVExOyXk5lwc6x/IrhcwKSEKIzRZWA0GQGFo7mQRBL0sSPTWjiffFruHFu2aiWwkE@ZQBjK74qsSg4gUM8kzK5C9SkE4K4NZYppUXJXwZaQpf9QkIFdZkwe3tjdT2tiStowdn9jZSktRCTzafSq2uS5JKMRsgrNOSZPI0EAVgDvekUusbkjTgCPDIqyR10bOVQ7VUkjT0bFS3tzGfS/SkMT2AXfEY7tFdzyqAGejJZEivlaTPHjqAq/KMVqikW@jBPDFmm8dsQJwkvXTLk0oBhiMOxzHsuHWtViVpl3uqVYx5RRXP8qK@Rk@VPpJkgQd4UJI64OhYYIBLUgOcyImS1ARXc6RAGN7Ni6cjDUeRpBEnEJJIkoYErTSvJFChRDhms7Ozo3Sdltrhn5HFn00oGsRow8HWduPly0an07BG1a2XRxjz6tWOcjkaWI1OQyRr1OFjQhqIueqNpj9Qxt16XdHnxryGGGMqpj6qq1i2uvIZyiQ@HcykV38FMa8gZt6CCccGnx6ANvCz3oPnutKgGPdDMfQcNhpSCXnUGfVVnFnBLkNbjEr@kJ7StMwSukDnZouhcCg2OpdrsdsSxbAeY@HIXap0jyDtML1nBGUiKDh3o/NhOVUDTVsu4aRPeLH3XJILWam4qDwPD9Gdk4qga69IkSK@o8Vsh1goLj8HcZdblYrL8JSeSxlwDsOpUIox@Imcr9aeS6uIRHr@PC5BWcALIAoklFYLiLCwCuN@6R7o4YBkbQwctV4Ph29U5SoS4XXi73ViZ2dnkTu@rUqjOjqldngYG5Z5aZgWKd1C4acxtfBA6KDpmBbH1wEK3D5PFamSkH1egtxZMhlZQ4GEIgSen2jWOsGKcf5GEzmfiyRwE3bdbNfp3QLskzu1fXY245r1g0J4hmcp6Bylu@mGdGG7GDhBrZFemMjwlHkD3zFEx2TBHOHXXdAbgVTQIQuBQEWoUSfq0EnsqLgBplkSYRv8XGLCdy4XiPJR6@MN9SU6f4sHGt@YhtJiIpjdUPb1SqVcL9@e1@JxLO7aWnANsnJT7A96bF1A4oEId094vbwOpUqVDLzZQUXv0jA4DFRaiqOAPbZ@NygWAfa@1CmfY@Iv@LMWlyoS5HP@pQb6JrTZKKiU7UGDbgBgqQYoxLnSEMLk1ZWSzpQyP8mxRPu5lFK7HP4eWOaqDIPHUpulWW6l5C9oOFIiFOXzdKoQS8swesCoAgHwXa0tLob1sGNuGVCjVLGIFVPKFfLCU4lE08t6uGUyZS1@C/wKnQG31UeielhWZRaJXsVZdiVSCi9Gyrb6mSvFX3ScBl2sl1NcPV6yB73z1GJOjt3F6/F7XbGdJXk1XTwfLJ3HZShC6ktnTfoIRAAq3AdAk/bP0sKQV4Iwlxf5IDke5sZh/RLoLboKNJML6ZIACfRFhwhLLIzvvuJbj8Kh0Go6FIqESgC1CMHUryJ31A1C0DlDz6BLwjALfbKQhnhLdQagz4GwmCkBNwFyciB4H2hpdp@tFALBu8D93f1axVWXXrPRSInGXe8zxjpRMAaTtKqE61GL5IonKi9YtVztHFVLArS6QSZbMsAu@IG2eHLxW9euomuV7/nzApcsIZsAJw6t7CbXohWa4ghIkhSU3IWHcD4Ldh7OpvwQpAso2cZde2DQWfLiGySXUuTa33kt8sO@pt/lM/EKWRLAcvf3wehaEpdDE5UkEat5QLsFAkHDFE6chnag24LcyWYlNCpV1j8ufL/6ff77N6cHpwfb7EWqmC/mOSUuuJ0Xk0NyCCj7AhQe7WgrEOx/MbPyD8arUrDYD2VWQpkJRfWiLI5zh5EPwue4UgPf2jmYi7UIuMpl@bm8WtRssZASLtqDvmpFnsu5dDGdkiNBu4JnTdOrQSASuuTcarAW5EhXViPgpjWAtBysJEWwvIrp4twHLJwN2oUvwXQqHwjm33z6wpj7yl4tTa5kUhR36X7tHv4r9@dgKN@TvXxP//iThJ97DkD/mMD10GP8mYAbw4zjaz/E1/j/Gv1sHPCSSzloiuAn6Pu2/X39@3owECyEKtFkCF8/zz9DYYSi4rps0J9qL@Pf9@OAZdu2lz0feJehzixbkRmousnkReRtGpTcQiGXzwUDv579JJfBYl5eqLIQv@WJDxJ4x6N3oik08RItnORYXohvHh9svN46wVFCNfAlqGzjYD@BUfiezvGRtKauKpY@Ei/qHCEUDi4nG4fMtNjp5iGlOaPDiBRKcxkil6XdVlG8zSZ2zeREBhfIssnUSlLOMjlfTK0W0zmmgDCy8fIB4VrCpIyqtWH2R9w0CW9EKPFCFWEwbk8D89BWi@zl4R6loHsJlhc2t94csIP9vQ8JN5SHn@zsHrPjg@2Ts@rRFtTjzdYxk6rHbPdYYme7JzsHpyesuv@BQfRRdf9kd@sYESQDKMhQVeIE8@wEtmaP7CTqUTYZCxPBttm8Up3JcMXqK0m8tHQy2MBXmKh48f9k@MCAUbblt0OOqwtcKWGIXmm1rACegtSabAGNkIVl1cKtwlI3Za@y7OD9bcrKLrLmyn5olTVT@0ZmbZXpKfHH9JVe5ogtLi5eGJI3Cvir4ZlB/iDcPw9h4zLtftxaCOdW2DIYP@mVyDhm/@BwIeX6Fs6OThZkL@5ocyHteXa3FzKeZwt8K55v@2xzIev51quvF3LjZPsbC6ueb3NrYyHv@YBJFwpjnPubC3Iq4BLr2tRaC/SatvD27t4WWwagSGkiFmeY0DEVDIQIDwybX0lBdt/y8k3XjJEW3RhNQbfUr0G74BNQC6gEnSNdazG2bPbhp6f2ABiSBTy1VrE6zZjAihf8wNgSuAssYIUWsEIAv4CHoRGOLZZZOsIgeqHN1@rD/MK3GJNObTry@J3N1lBBrQAzxOjGIDr6CilU8b7GwMK9QBlu0yxcm/bzEijYCkyypEgEz8vtn@7t8cxgdLBMKywRJCOPNAen2QdsUEX4xapDKG8c3izUFkirBaFa4DslA/cTrRmYbk0kBdRzYaEJCCape63oMYaqVQzXgBEvevg@fACGaHCnwMUPCobDTaxrR3WaVKAIEnPrYJvXEFeRy2yylSMMMyVKUTTf4f/lC3N9F86k15r0GiGOWyDnxeL4eEnLCBvBsAX3hCZB0Gl0SrmAHBONQmqoDsX56rUARIcvP7zulrICGaVC7NkzKsca@AohygLTRSlHFkcQRCAIRuRDZF7RFqm4kYXkMm7y4C9kRyLiOMLvEG2MvIs3QLJOF3SqVb1e6DXnggFmWWlKIIuodgvbGtyZdB38KB6Bk2OsAd0kxtxIOYeRaPXEmBpjbQiekql1zQDOVa2xTHRZATojtf7@Jm8hfssMhfMAqjHIvSI1GAiLZ9h9idEXFhoWGKclFwrkIUEB3yLThJEQHO7xdEeblGyZ9xdkS0z9lJS720WXj3hqYAfBaURWvBiA84qoLgVWxkAz@AUy7L9lQM9ZkiOLRgWEx2UCbGsSLh7ncPcuX36lElvTtVj85lqgWH6wFltPrMZvVgsY1sYsArUAER8GvFGApp/J1kzPQwFjIaGg2vw0FDCAjnkJ@vgEgiekhyF3nD7@7elhkC5Od2Xot9CCXCrwJJPe5qS3NenF7gshCgObIL3CvrAGuuQcuPCAOMuDo8Vl5WTC9qSXJkXKTHXTtD0JzHMAnkNRycGQAWeFMUqQhI3vO1B6@NadMqtu13f3t04mYxFfwq6LgnfxZfaUR2QSTBQI4@0weiJeicJtJALXN8OHPI8Y0bN@fHK0VX0Tg/JF2Nq4B0zrAPAjesJEDe7dHCDUUJswHrdiLHxcZcsR9gxLFmNixgA9T85CN20VUD2YY2vQT1NWKQ7i@Sd7UhB7ZGBOVlKYhSPsy8UFDKmpVSb3@l8yvYyxmmmxUWYVlV2Ox9NBhJR3Bcw@75pc2UDIFr/crjg3s8tUiq1YGeaoXdC4hylrFj/V6x7HNhoW3WOsfZOMMrvE8NQwyhZx6QeMi5OqzeNaJI2NyAcYit0YwnA4p6m0KOnnyJ4U6ypYvCwt9VvL8jWNdrIscV6WNcp0tgy/FpOPYC4Fpo4q090pZt/pK3iaV0Qe9HFG5RCDrECAz7T4rtAKm/imEydSpKtPUKbU63irZb0etlW9jS9VH1hNGPJRXbYFGH4wNsEjqSOhYzJSkAf1p8mIloanb/HOQBh1phDSu93LdGFfmHIMBLyS2Y7ap1L5ioGTZfgKYH@GYGBP@KFZ8VScr8SRotCKtxXsDy6y84lbjziOgd2NzQkG8Twb6rHpnDiPbebE4eV285K4p7XnxF0OevNKAILhgRhx3nJOjGEezEvALw0aR9TOfQQ89xO4VgtH5jc99KvJFvfd@kT0P7EGqrjCaPfAx4KgXAoO9LV1cFMFpm1qeH/8NCLvxDekDA8jvsPnHltFxpyk2E1Nm0bvYhKI6PQkXZHOhsVmF7B@J6fzkZgPoQ9ji9@h@RBO5kMKJZyDJMiOiffdOVDbQ40sOI13nD6BdycYLTDvxgnM/iPwGDuGxcZ3gRfw2isvxmPmOV1ujK44yzgUjjPv2PzyxAVhD0G7lZAjfoL@ptnHvzX7uC9/7JM/KesyO58sRy3q8xchYFxHt4P/pIzcUk/mFvmmGvu5RlWvHmBfvMjFlw2/wGEyWw@NkEAeT7lVIfQY8EQhgbj8iL5BvlDziePl81KPx5/lMovLXhou8ca9gSbXfYUP4NUT9Tre2Vqv02V99TrOLNXrEs@BBl4c8PyDruhsPC4BWmrdpNiwFFekmBSPV483dnfjmiHF@JXcZcl2TEut451bUgxXVMsSCaw6wnRVvV@WxMY2xWaUWno4j6ovD6jg1zMhIJ7LrkGZjC9j/Xp2TX@VzCdUyZzKbHxB5BNyO6Lc8Cz8YzlZ/KY1N6MNugwMb1ezVA0FDb9sXLw/G2/NmLisAaf0RRF4vjbN9Nl4RQYvEj3qGCbaGu@aoMXeMqPZPsm9PEaauetF9Hac6kEEY07l3Ccd0iuJGF0k1lKFnkXTQwlpfImkKFhC1NTH766Cxu/eGA9okxfKiPLG3LlJG6cxp4o6FixmHyt/LuF9M9AAh2Yffr07Z8Dt3ToDbrx3BoNcUQduvHQGU7SFQ9w/Ay66gQaewN7S@MLLnjLUegOcuPHfaiA0uXGxcMjHmtCoT5GT0o9TFCESOt4cHBZ4I1GpKEHVbbrtZvrGG4Sfd@lNpBaYFbJ0RTMW06c6zEM69xqdSOy30Eg@RQxFsy1KA2ljEpO4EkJp5WINjE8f77giBtXnqTCTz3oiIqhJzEs/Hq98l@aUJ8wLpAgYD7ww4wR8lsn/6j9S7iNFTwUZt5gfiituc8qNW1MfLLgfg6uoRQKPWFL/v7GT/E3yX6ip9P@9UTRj@vyOTZlHTJhvtlZ@i2bBf1Xo/6tC/xMU@t@aNv@ASj6NcrbHT6nrX1XDv139Ipk3gmHD6lzj1Fv6p@hhvyVFYPWb9AC31OfyY7rA18dnF03aP6z/xFE68OvkSSt3tm1Wq9WTnmwdvax2qt3qEd5PtJ7ai55drqxv3qy/XG9VNzc7rzob@@rbfHVlr//6ff7Dy/btZxW0952DVx9v9X6zG3h/1L85Uw9vMmrerg4Gn3d3Rs7O@mlv4zj7YfUmtaVn2@vq503d3nxz8v71ycvscfTm86vDV7e9VM8@bKeUQi@z8yb3bmN0ZgSy19ppa3tPO@gdt7ZO0729Te3DdnQjtXdceCun9rZuPmY2bqLZVHK3//rg5dHpZWPro360u/ehtfHZVHKfr276u8lWob1xefQucJB5K@98PjjobKULL3eSN5vtfiuV3tGt7OX7o8P10w873dfKVm87e1p4fzk6zHXfvr129qOdlbPc4I29EjWqb9@mXxsvr6@3jgINxTyxMuqZ@Vbu39wcmoXeqvp6f6fTe2vJRvIg@y563Du52dxa1z@vDjOnH87e3qwcfxi8efvq40FKOz5ubCm5fqOVPr48WQk0e5nd6PXp1mleedk6e9u73t3JfthMvumq@9XWoX71srPz0Tw@3NutZuyBIe9tXOsfXnYv31xtbuzq5uGVblRXkln9pPXh4CBw@kprbKo77@1X1cvuh2R2/WrlQ7TVf3lyedu9erV@fHqQTw8PRylzwz5q7LSHm0e5dD7Z1D8f3bbNN/Lp22ju@vJVWvtQvXUCmdtRtrCnf1B7xqtos/Nx@FlPRk9leePj7u2HD8c711ajapx@frd9dGm9aRkH9kHq6NXrNw39Ku9c9j8ax8dyM/VSvXoTTSmB4emODW2knijZ1ZPe3tv@cNP8fLT70c7dRq/PrjLq5tXRu@rno1Tjxui/N6w9rbeRah0o1XemszUYvmwWrk@vdvS9zwf2h8CbLTmb3Tbb9nr73UrhffJltH318v26fDxM7RtH7ZWctf/u7ZmmbXXfn94eNbPb7/r5nmN03t6e9raiW3vD7q2aTzX04w9XRuA0e3x0mL4xXms9Z3vn6E3OOUjtvTts7Yzk6ltVvjFWN0bZzaGVy5xtvrc@XO0Y/eQH7fPgMKVeR1sf@s7KW63Rbr7Tmr3XgeNX3dP9w3c3u9mc9bJnaOuH@dT@3s7Gfqe18nq0@2awtde4bL3cfa@@75/krtJb62e5zffHGefk6rVTaF73Mof56Ineczqn0cCrQXewenhmfX43/LhS7TXUzJH@wRytyr2NV/308F116@C2c3XYN/fl7fQoebpnXump25Ob2x07Vx1F88NTp2c6J/IwK78NZG5u@86r/qu3xwfrrw4@vlJWNO1MuTx@10plTvNJrWtldnO5l/LWdrv3uVdQ5dvNNxkl0@tG7b2rZGujdfru7Eq/7L3uXTYD@YLdXN/9OFDMrUZaTn1Yb29l1b31vRNZPe28Pl7Z3E8dvm8dnn4enrQ23g9O3x1oqa3LV4W9zsr7o3eF16sfT@wT5cx8/9raDwzzGdOWc4XsTea4kD/oWseZs8uC8/H1ZW5dP2vIr3bTPXVbs97nR/mr/m33pnNzrKYanZebn5Wj9hZI0tPDlJIdXO0PjwOZdye969X@evTDVfP1e0PW82faavLk82Xhqtt9fbPZXDmr3n5Wsi8v1cLxdrKhb2dfRo823h5edjbPbvMrrdT63jvl/XCr63wIvN3RNi8LZ1cHw5H8dvt41KumDD17fXyWvT4x14/Pdo7z3TcNq93YueyCbOiNTi9vBtc76mp3eJN/3b18p6T23uc3DHvlMBV4pe72Wkcnr99Xo@20WnCuDz7s98/yZ8Psm7x5VjAP8trravvl8O1Beyu12tfOToanW93k@obWy4NMOdRPrY2Dtzsfz171U4G0kVu/3TCzq5@j18MPubPkYXRv8KF5ku6dWdbOe83afn99@P71cXU3utsYvTy8Ug4@bGWP9zc27FfRbS2njnYyN3Z1I6O3zYDdWx/uD61@IfPxaq8DI4HZKrRenmTODLtabd/s5o@3qtWXdmP3lTIcvmyvwhiBn62zd2Y58Gt@91yAXzvHHwq/5yLQszsNcwjykh@VC9BJqACdhArws0@0T5rvQf51cjlw4j8GQC@u5RM8gwYoa6xlovKQYLveBbH4fogY65mQXENX0@zTE9GKsw4tNPh0@KX5KjyMR6/dU4d93dTw1Tv4GgC0Sa3xG7ISgQOD9UZobzpqjx9O0PDtOeI@V3pzAH9JEd0nGVhoNpn7csIE3VbqvarwEygQfaMTp@tpOyweb7Z1pWODQ2@R61Pg2Ls@HXPQNQUnPzALea@uyKms2JpKBxewcCf40p/9l0w3@XsJXItDAWViRHd84CQV3fOh4gvMbO1a1Uf0ogm1lQjwHZ9P2gXpD8MN3pNhdKfm1N5QUDdUa2oDaJ8ndFdak8sv8AqWF8tJscSKylBdsRqag6/HrfNTDXWeo7vnrT@595COyIoFWq4YoWZDt9HGxJGfIfqmUiHFaKM5nitwRPaoGqKK6u42XF7uE0rad8W4x4d5uf8wbq3X@W2hnsDd0tQJvCbQagC0ogXpmTX772za5OgBlQJ8sX7r/e5JXbyNhG8xnDhI9MCOSx@VS66vX@I18JVflHx2WybuMIDi47Qjv8wZqnptcl6WaN8jbo@E1kYLe7zbkl7/jkVHbH3ajXK@UuM7CFO0dc8luJfmGeeEZ75SPRsTdEFsqPB44Inp@AZNDjJbX0TctlSVAGg3p3s@ZGqz32@Z9x5omYauGFfoKvGtsmAvWE1fY9F7Fnz1wKksry5i/yTZCFhvSOptgx0XVLK8ZiEAsSHWbeZTA7sz7bfHNLyFvaxxfgzz8KwuXTeb4XH0srvlhtct4ubE4aeyOsCZxDburDWtEc8Ip2fCpRKA4D4dkgmq4e5W9dW6PKYGoqNNPb5SAN@W3CA8j6@Oyxljj5eWZ7VI7EA7gOYXlW8GQqhzr1g1ntXDshDoHfFXZiLpmDjuFiJwJpeZY/aBCG3BcTCMEY/w3akzVOE7vTwuYpxO56ka/LPnfk@Rb9zFDoXnvRmKkAh2Y7TQpwrnFRpBK17XwazGrEcNhTu4sQk14kWmgYWP4UyLRifayYf8XEO6ySxK1A7PiQUx5NVIkF7QnmBoTxy0Bt@Ky9p8BxendWCKRGuQ0ZcvXocBr8eNh@7pRWAJ72XcyOCcM3lfFgQtuX63E3puihkTxZOq97N76enUJhjg5k1fG6p6GARmHd@y0mcQJLYs9fvcQRDe9iUIxsamsgt5tbgYhlTnBJfM19gzFpbX1sKr8TAFfZePRLzOKJKnfcl9iUFIVyosnF4OZ9zEK5gYUGYmEazMR5DmCFaWw7KLIC0QyFnAwFUMQvIdy3OunUSc9yH28NYmYfBdLXNyX05H5draWh73ePoCpxKn5xd9ORNNQ2KOeiE6GcPR8ghfeG2yRoA8k/aNIz4UK9EMoOBZRycjxrlORXiZ@vNcqc0dnH5ryot7TsMdfCg5vjJStc7zWF/kVL4pvc/A3XcsEYiv7erTy7vGYZyll5HNQUegLgm5dVU8NBXjL28TgxbQrzQ1KvoORxAEigEigotHi7HLx8a6xrcPdgjcpgk@XucYk2MsD2YISBSQGHlIDCKEaKB16s1e34ODoTgf4Tu@@QBGmezjijOeH4B2QrXfzYnEGCcfrnADPvHyLBpDOH3DkKC@t7uOj3dbR7hjdnf/JTThAtYjxsa/bjUXOUavihuKwV/ooTkaFAFkGzdoRF15U03mj4Fu/gKbi1zAT2PnCal2CMF4YqEdEl9oTl0zBTZOSpePVIfoSO@X8gDykRLYGexGZYqO5Bjx9@Lm@Wuo6NAbpSZSgcNLKAqIFEKanRxV94@3D47eEOUO69W9w50qYgYDs6lYLUYvSsEOYhiqzgdVj54BHH47@J5nrJPScN/qwd@AjbD8jXuceABYp5g6hU6XCOvLmX4GngfPS0ASxYMGpaLeUvtzcOPeVQ9MVMaeg5C3Ii@1GApFmeaNhDTgzY6ErhytoKQjWpqqbYQcYGx6cYxicHmSdPGtg5VJb92jnot6VIf4xeKvGcuk6d3DyEf2oI@rw2pL8pNfaTZVm64LGFMfUKp6mzIRksVHKAiZX/ux/OBnU7yxV@CgVy/SoJvy9N6xmjupLIL2yGn3k3Rcn4LEsbg60p2rVpJaJHLmr0KeUB21SZXxocx4bpc8t0vIjQtcdjmtkGm188sJRWweeTSXPJdcN3Y1M66eeFvJqeXa0OntLl7hQ3MhXOpQg2Ez0fUV5mhC1j1zm@yZ24vHPXG@cve4UiYIO6mRiQFnPH4Kg7nVArKFZ@Y26OQKWV8DC9ufewz1Bj00UvKDTq6JQfDEKXVQp104V3ziGaoHOQMxgTSk0zLnIrsaDSoevrBAyOJueSI@XYNOYYpZAc0AaTE@nCbqSqqkaQtD0ReIYlWMwlbL7eQEOR7MrNb0gS4EwlB@4HB8KoEf4@MZ5dFJr20sE2rkkLHOShFcV43HIUGEz2uQTgPiFutAxdOc@dXIz1ZDVM7VyTR@AgZFnXDLXBQg6BeweyDUzbw0t96@eriH4TBxxFexVEmcoHBP9J4esoycyfiO/x6c7bNcbnw6GG//Yivp1PjIMd4DxnKFwE@aJxvPJ3B@xI4jGhTZCnkGTXfQBVVdh07MHy0Nh34sGzeLh/wxKnnK1TK3YG0hjsXQYLMevhC@oeKLz3G91mHyUE4EFkAo0hyweKOkO3gDYGegWIrhqPyMJQpysbKLGVJC1GFVC@qFb4KnF86DxMf3ocOwYKl8AhhCWmaTNkkiDkoHLT3o0W6kGCoM16qF1wBojjjov0AyR7ADFw0VzgRuoCscKi5vcBIKkUA9GidZOBlpWEbq8akX4UqTunKyl6JSnuzJNKS5L6fFAhB5BasQjbk7sCAIPDPMkD2@LN7Q5XZJD3gs@udNDc4OMtw4de1wgYaPMbOWv1abMxlD3NX0j0FDsYmJUFGdahH3DBxJAPcIVNOdh@BA9BjWaHgiXNwaRQri6@o1PhfOSEaQFkGjFA0pFnId7tIRN8NR9IL3em7i5zL0vojYGTASB@a845ECAlk@wiHE2chpCOyfHGLoxwGl4B11OTnefzBEHN55NxTfxCGuFY7uiLALEAG3a0nt4uXnZ9Lm10L0UcqUH0mbLilFRXx9eT4Yr7IAw9r5wKBQJI/cSrlgp4fjc28uIJWeJqQeK/xEbk8tvMhuBmiCEk8sukeIezFXNw8pJO6Z1ypfpBLbaoSa6WsfriRBIwpGIJ6lfi@mKgQNXKnAS9fwpeA6s5vGlSQUIw79zoocAeU5ltPucWBXoHvTnONzvfMqyjnZrapbTWpBekW2rvVpaJysq@gW/rrG5dnKrvoq654ynqisSOTWc/Z@BwMcbd284fcv4IAiiZPL0netGPuuhYshIsQ/RrnUmCf/Js86@zrk9@Vxj/Tq55WVDs16Ht5XxdohinY/v2M6xJtyOzm@I5mGABnBTaPkbq7nqRYWhDoDSs9EunRETDt77OyiaLdBXtNWfbzvdS/tYhpzDGEpsx84HhqCblVrAtgF@0JyHgsQ8WDxPfF@WB8XCck80Uld7sCIaFSMZ@WJ2eDxAeoHGdGPRchO3xHlR9OTTJktxQjj@DA5H4ebRAz34/5f8hdk9GBBkBy0RiTGOm/NiF@JcP@broyOdbe@0NxA7@qn4eezUMSE/pZNuXpAuD/WFzzrgNsDft1AKNquMogTW6DAg23Mj0bHGOT@IPz4hpHPfIEPj@ZBSroBxJ@MrprwCyRewrTPLOr7jJjZYlLrEEX7vE0my00NSRMhHnZejWf9c0SWTMdxGZA7o/JMrSbQMTrkTLNxJX75B6myeFE32an@2z@w4Zex8rhkObaz@ng42N3tQCi0Xl9X@ckdea9ePdj1rrZi4qXyqm1ikJ0wrU7yRrvSkhwwcCyurYqrA@zneEkVj6lvncJQhhdOOQl2rPLNCqj3olr2icxJdRD5hInwBiwDgNtt0HiNpoovCXFucP@AQGAn/IWFaMUGPdw02Mg0G@PSK@JkDi9AjMpuQ@E7QJhBIwEFSDYVx1ZHahITJhs6/PQUvHU5CSZ5EmuYPDDUPUh9DF1CTVwq10pg01cwOjk9lStdRBeI49wRxTj4Tm3aPYJzCA69V75hQtt4@1OFkUDXNpqGPmIGXgHQoYshGb3mF7JCzruBatKOW7GoQ1seVLIjVlKFHAl7W4xwlA7H70QC4rKRAH8fbBHPd9gmsoul0t5USj6xp2VqTwbvmJObKLidPxnWxMu5vr5Pw9vikUz60prGU/Z9zNvjQfd/Adkf2vmRTOL0aF9XRky6Uei@a7axsprKFdHW0joGsSH2FrxEx6exq8M@vlUVNwbgOO6m1dVrVWcZbMZ3mj0AwGNnAFUKBPuW0ukpLmA4U2SYje@OLrKvJ070j6NMU58MaeO5CTa2qPFkGmPyGBud4BKjChJTBItxQY2A1IKf57jl2TT7rAiOltoYdGgwwHNZbgo8HaXEGphAiVTCjchzeBbhCUXHIi1DP8bOX/bur8L9RKbGzqGb15i7QCGVAlQL6PplXvqSmx5HDgTzrejAgM1XNWBEWGZ1YYzyWQKAxjEszOFsPu9Ji@cuSMvcPcBZG8qQby52Y7CKfXHd44N7SpaZb08JiAS8bwoZk67ASibdmZFQFd@P63rWQzyWZo3C3D2eIuKj3rJHDnf/QpvvPlmjO8EY3eRJ5IyU3F31condu4C4BwQ1HNxZEg@5OwdQw7RwbWa8IwVIL7lW2GNofQXIfAWSGg7ZDMclXzX4Bu8an@0SKsh0tFxz17AgvJwqudTgr9P22n@8mPWMt@YCVXyRXs59x4Q6LTX5QgytkogFpomy4uAleIS4g@MSQ3yY8wMFTHKDmE2kSdOYN6HKC8rnXEFYoM4ZpyElxoasg7Pv3HyKsZHw4u3uAX6Bcyo2Kssl78Zn1Rj07tAYifEkg34Mge@ZCtK@FMBfYdFZPHOvd8MoQWIdBXmABAUGnbvhOLVxl4ox@b5EOTfplVlcxIMeMcv7c/diXRiIr3gOpgj91/gwUfyuJcV4frhkQA7ZdaRrsXFunIheqYcj8yo8jI1AdDA8j1QRVge6xeQ8eUe@KLqjRKzTCAGD87B1Bdcd60i7sHsDGasPy2Ag1UdlnMPj93@hwsu7BV0gg/BFBoDxOAKChcpcZZfiicwg@obRKMaDUTcZP@gX0cp208/EY@sRfp7ej/9@fEke0aE@jNVHEXdfCqSoj5aJBN72lPuZ6lLxfoP6zpR3qr4z9PDq@wA9vPrO0vMn1debMX5PFYEhhh5o46DJ/hwsaoD2Avk8xXOGganxCLX5YTr1oI9v5plKTW9dmE1t9vumjReEzy8Bz3NOISjeFw55Pud5FMENBnKSTx/J@RR0PbxJ3w7wLm6ZqC@GyY3vP@TjF@iTOp/bFmM0BSDmAs3oe974lB8yiIihxB/kikSvfpgVl6lcnQC17Yr2F5eZL6uSV3CqKLfBGCX2ah9h3OvD4as6bV@E0rhJkFARNi/JAPUOTDedBMPmJxFUF/JxMhVSnc1N5TYipha7K11NiMSOtMutpLHWLfnWmuoknYFdffqEZ8d6873DqMvgvDFopjcUdUdpMMV22zTbtsE3YrNDMTuFx55AhXe6ljnodBleFIU6IMLyLeVtE7V71C5Bq8eXXg7wrpqiuy0uPK6@N3@cZKd9BkY@nZ/HnvvmkG2g4t8Y4VwynwsI@4YJscNqYcHVnRbGU9oLJOk94Bqf6OMzDuPsqc18BdhEfoAivMGZOMj@iNhpTsbuIBaXPQ1EUhxH7fUd1Kw1XgWs/jhZH5dhxglRA3Dv@CJlZcEDnV9Yzsa@0lLp/MXdA1aZV9rU3ELSMdTpQjZUnOpLPVI4Pos4PXcDxcHcsTSb6u@g/bxc@eo12P1fYU3I1OXKGMGpYOTi5mhQdvBoXg@vIMebNTinggUOKPdNC23DUWwu5hucj6PepdyA7UWmMsJFE6I4XbBnr3Gj0dzUtOLWVaCp6OgAIoISkGrF185wvQzfgoap35A56iXmBrBNqhzeO8uLYTZxldlNPEsJy2yqastGlVVBXqFyhvF4g@iu7iphS1M6aCGCpe6KXrc4NB9N1mJXa/JTGRuHWBRL/TzQLG5sY2kS0Ja07wdYYaOrNq8IFl8INMYe14w4kM1w4mab2Z8HioVTDqbFoiE7IGQ8H2mOxE6caT1KCKjSBDBxXnlWCfEBo/qJV0FOsZU7X4dTNa7Mo806@IKLkC3ePCHmjJC2/rkfnDVJMJBX3oQMDM@6OKGr2YTHZ37HWHugoyw2@wmMQ0k4WVm/DxXLxmKZX2I4UU2fZwKIC9bJWB9GsQ3F8jCEaRgXIzGXNF8HL8xAY1YPAMc5tGdj@ejrEQ1IOUG3ieUdOhQ0nr@AaJo/DyO/2S5MG/daWKowITBNKhKjTGbR0lA8i9UwjbgfMwebRQxwCBZ5avuV/19qP4YKkIGyBwQMHn/HGcamgpOVVHRhfUJPp1oiI4uqgBzoDXRHMVRzYOuj3zUjBBbo5ZZCd4agEXk/CO@kOo5mGLfOkvgyALabPKDtbrg3AQ11EN7pvSLGSCdC1GDD9UwxzjJdHIOxY@6bbXCZKHyCcXsiDgdHd0/AVAxemYAzPbhNwKEzXjG@bQBEJx0XM5wEpXM32ClNZ0BCtGvi5grcUzrA@SDc42HhETFqEhTYWBdEbvZVi2cG3DYyB8wdn4Ffx1d9goAc37WpQaZi6CP8KJuxWsj3fCABPIjbh@r/ae/ZlttIrnsWvqI11C4GxJ2iJIrgcCmJ1C4TSWRIymsXhMXiMiBHAgEYMxCBpbAV555KKlWON3bs2E7lYieVvCYpO65KHvK@/gd/gf/AOZfunp7BDElp1@tKauXyEtN9@vTtdPc53eeCKofHrlEGtl9oOIDT3RG0Wx1vbVfeUeDhxq9bGLoSa6Bq4S/i9tgGLqzwjWvjVzi888UqEXesXAXdCsBiM27JWM/evi7l@5wS9GP6T8Qyq7suBcsEJXX78SWBtCoWr@WUAOvVSNHC9hzU1NhACwtYlwBa9xrXHXxrYa0NujvDWTwDAnFb484JdAnmy0OCCcY0Tl2vS8MGMhxee2tX5r4A9BhtKMcM9GBy2kaXND0aL22mSe8eeEkOIHaIOkc1h6aXHu1wXh7o@RmqetL9cTen1xZXRXIJCj8AqO@R8ASVbaL7Szkw@B1qNunR6dnyE69CVnBY8LsuE9FNifRHv5C10lCe67XIt1KLY6xegDEXXp7FTMLwwiswVJzOhuMX/HKE12608wctj@698S2QFZaxkLrRw0d@P8zjlwx1OReGNaH1jAfLSSu4/JJXUVMAm2KfDXrYcCocYH7Dq4VKy1obucK0BVtYh2@gyjILNaO4LL9c8sauiUe9ufIdItsGVUzTLTnWjrkUeK7lVSbbtY37PcldRWhDQkqKQGjVcrx@l1eSqo4ioSEobjzLONT4vKPAatLcqWimzFH853aq4ZO04g42K2o1Mn04DlNHWIdWEu4YqrrLyryB9ckiw09hZh0dwOHNxo12DL5OrYmp1O8iS6spa3hdi8nfgntcR5b02rXZ64wOjYVWEw/v5C2iZrkMSO7QyoArTBsxKU9tjD1e@gmmKlLJk8MdwPEuMJiCNN@AT/My3A9y@rleLlA/KPkB0Y5x0hd59wH6Tlp3rb4/lK7M6GDlQj69F77eS4xagVy9XHftSQ@bgi/9UCY0UFm0Trne01sOqebygz@PFIGT3uEEcfD6zxnagsqhPlutABSZrMgXflmwru7EEb1Uo@7JOzLugVhuymplH5QLI@wEPXgb7mxIqnp37B7DnwMPW9T1s8gv6ZfvUmabLxP393afHO0cNA92vrJzcLhDJUmRXxsUT0Zluinzz9C590DizfoRhziZ98cenON44lCcJZTADzvDIBAPQdx1QRx/0YKSrYmbSX1zX3mUnvfUd8frXP6ImXkyvidNY99DE6EJqipB/85YAOfnYdvPMfHDGUgOqVDrtY@eDDguVAb3TNjMOQf3T1xJ7SFF2yUIadmAR8qwF5whByiliegbM5w0/S6sZrckdWwVNF45hP4StEMEZAAgH7VuZyUK6W2uVRh4F3hOZCOxrRyvF2TvBxWxz9VuU7Vim/uFPGSrPxwcZ6T3BKMFxLnBoVXAgOHraojJKAiqQL0F9BSII8094g6VUT4oV0uV8ufn0iB8xP4NeSt4A5P8N7TzXrTTT4yflGS2r2IAGDzOPGZDFwmblGhBlxytKWpQF6toRVb0Zubk6dbkEv3N37AFeYoBuWzd6hdjNP752nNf2cz6M/tY@OLNcBIJOGKVo8g3UcV0/vkZ7PxfsRp5PXORy6wovjSdSDadkAHVXsd4IrucJe1j5Dx29/jCHq@a9PWPr7S7ZTijGE@mdq2Ioq2OYBNVmg/j0UhN5Ksp0Uc06CNq5b82dfj0vibYAoTdTVY7fo1eG8YRkY5WXksTXgfquUTF3dTWn0far@o11fZRpX08Q94zvEjDNSebG1WRpt3m1SsRUQNnSxfW8SXylxrm2rxFOZU3LuOUMro8O9SdGZeMqb/zpWBCaR3kLZAxsji8VjTEnKRW0yZRwlVqEYV4KUflFK754vjF1NbDEQwvS8mJmHmJL9tqL@PYYCAqOhvQ9iAXn6MIyvAyNg1ldGrUXKRVJhfagk2IfoH//2JtpUmQDTy@NLL6DRpZfWk18qXVyJdWIxdZjSxdL0/8cbntDcrAmvVF8Qy4/8wSLKjtPfH@e/eOxNF7O@Lh0we/Lb6291S8f@8JpOyJ/af3H@0@EPD/nSeHO4IK6H9fcceoci9g6rfdjku38yuVyqogzAsBylfFYetUvDfsuC@BeDb81unWCX@UBm6wyaV2Xrrj2ZCfg0aozBJIqwm6K@K3JnXjhBbXbaDkU3xHVL48sY3kzdPnmyWyvaBw6NqAm9/2iAchPS56VtJGGwA/hFRA0@InWdKdxqd1Ylq6JSEHTv977REEpvDxobj3ZBsjfW7vHu3uPTkUD/cO4HP/a@hmR2zvotuY@08xiwAf723vPtx9cI8SuAGVksC7NTJYv6gJJQSnUem86E0wPFgfpUL5FfHqvZTJDIbKKsIX2ckgdN/TBZLCd3d2dlojF@32jXsH734FuRr368KyMMil4VBdWiDcqKDRCNQmo2jX2Jk6spbFKm9IpzNxA7NrGboDot8FoZDn6J3Yc4X1AK8R8UGa4mYzw6ZQQ0XXATeiUo5gHUERGLLZwgah3ITa6PZA1YYXqz31gUW3pGNWlCOXlJdWn5BicMbdQYfD6KoEoHvW6qZqgzED4IWQTGAAvIPBhKD1wt3FSxJxS0JMAhT8IeE2Jzw/HT08Q64RDVxlwn0OBLIm28TzRlOKAY5a3oDnMWLWxLsDxUihIj7Bo5Ocfl9duZJKHPD/8o0NX2UB0oJdsAcrWwkV4bMbUAPs7SetXuAL28nhbTCIIO7AY02t434LxD26Fx6jwdJLVCOgatcc/LepHNUrhpMCcSoRpj0T0Xboctvy4HevWg5K3l@oEfX2qNOoMCXjP13agPsLDXgTNICoaO4X6FZoFBBjS2iGPUnKtj8EigSRT3wcjWo07E46bqSAlHXs595HH@XkIBfCIoaKD7VOa9hhqAd8CDlDH1Tk5gKEGNKUPMHXKJ5DO9qD8G34FJUhxtjAD9XgytpM4UHVKDVxZKXIz6fU2m6RMdyltRLFs26w3r5G2mcUPX/7bJZHzyRtFJO1NOejP2dUYkDPTmN089ITqFg0C6glHNwhE@4dHwu/XP9gzdncvv@s@PGHhUa5fMzbQqvLjxeslMjPLCSSw/LQupOkDahWmkSa8SdtLK30GXm3xFWukAHjcuIB873VrOk8vlZdTB9QvKxoOiW@euVwqSLZmxAJYSSZcHcriLqqskBlGiInEYR7JzQWPeuqlALh1Pv1Fsa1x1mowYgMcB8h9RozrBrp1xjervFBD3aWjOTTeLo1/pyKRS4piv7Z5nyUP7DvO/nNXFlB0WLSw2mrLbqgMFdzsldznF46rxbQbV@MDvbvq6Nbu7B1fDy8FrbtC7G9VtuK@XRcfCwZuK6O9uML0PLh9kZooe@FdMR8SC5i05SuibNwY0nR/CU1frgwd7T2AA2evRhRVSM1apsM@ughzuZLcWgaFciZaEKG6PBoe@fgQFg7eMu2DmVh32sNOmRfitsg4r6uPB2xHTJtdiXNNOkwQZp5UilzNi@NVnvRYk4cvJStQvIgBTkeerPQUXtBMplK6wg@WYiFQMNr3hDVyEVbd672IL8uEc/rqAklwkkzOphJ7OYSHz7sZJ82mXDcCswb@y@8kWZm3Kl01kVX1eOZiUgxwngctI7x5Tt5/t5n/nhd1cMMlvv1CXUYlfA76C9fHELFI3wpLkVn8IJpUVNKOitEpUtq7MgsL8phf3aC0rHY55IXNrZ1yRzLpjF/fMOIZEf86Ra@889kZudU3neqLZ5SNswJzYWHnh09goDJBDFYbJlUAcUbc3mE0Wjoc9LRDLm51m5Qa@qqlRTNTOKupQO9BRz8rdvx7SFeFey2F1ZV/Hyq4lMiUpMRd2uxBpUJmG/funXzMtzxXqjixc@Km8@Q@P4ZnI5etgyU/swnVSGg3N0nBZUfEsAFQ@eAFNi11YKJFQRWJ@FMifSdDiOzfdCWszHa4kFj9p4eFfC@KF5rTkxjbUvGzieSiZ1AFvpgLGHdUV41C6M/v7i6@xTU7ZL6rr9@fbzYEAjvw@e/4jCZB8MRbpXAiI@b7BUVRPJ1H7XiAizBwQe1p18jBuaWimNZ53hzW/zCjTbSXONWMHyBev0qcqaMbWbhM1TptDU6f4UXXK/oypTz0CZAlvUKYus566hwZM2t7pCUCHo6lOUWtzKaBtv8y6YZfHMd1QcpjwGMB0xHD2D27awAuWcdbxVUqMlsntOAP9FJRU4CWg1Q9tDpy5yOdgneqD/T6WVO77oYeE6nbkgsZy0d8TK7KSHjETKzlgSmu1qvN2vSsOvsdzgb2Bid9JZsDMiW/aFOvc6pqFOlkuqy7CRManASSFI6aUlC4cHkBSYt@a77okmTLKPNAcJsQQy8fqMk9afesaXsmJMmHAFPJJR3B90MTQrFPNWo1JGwha5lJQnVt7xGiRQo5QaEMlk4sbyQtrywgAkM6UboSyYqLkYNwP/KRsimmsSLNde3niOFj12/M3HFzhRlfBUbUVElOQZZEjtPtsXeQ3Gwt78TRY0tbiKPQqWUwh6FYpYNo@6oJVuACR9OgpMmJ6rPeO6Zy7kKBX9roMFwbADxZzxXVUAoGrgsxfmr7itRh8N7pCfF7uYactJVj3UfSp3hZBCcv5q@oumdAqdXAhJ4R8xLeEnwzsKwyJUoOWxFDvQWh2Ehka9sKrcKYS2UQrVMpW@OobS4jq353Fxiy@j9E6YOViZt0mFATtgmcScYIsuzLuNbwnB0TsKAm/SW7QjbjjcMD6VSaSE5L@7owI2uGXE3WtkVK8mnVXI3rIQpTOMp@RhHNKwtJ7pD8cp7pSoLDxU8@tfi0o4ebfTdLKfROGJo2UVgKg0jm18ljD53M9FfCwtOzqCIxhuVrxu8IDDIe7ibO0zjETCi7wUwvTkoMF5AC3C0CiKAvEwWAKn8IsZmcivDpZdQJLnF4XpcbE5KLSG6hCLJtYSNjk5FuNZjs9EZAnfGAUnwRxMEQeN8TZw5IJuFitMWq4gXlKRI4kyT67T5Ty6hDrVNMwTQY0P9rDbY9EZkzWIXwkdHxGyB7LwxILgHkTsVPNbM9Go83TySxKZRPA5hNCoGDDhjJ9Xlc8GeRCJJZ2ipxcuKjLZkNHDkteTRCFtOwwAlEkoBLUZBedWEsACKIMTF4cligPJKjILmk0EN4id4E2usrcZq1KD5ZFBjfSxgLSZhjYLm46AL@xptlNGx1wztsn3x5OVS@FgTnVGVO3U7k4BPGuW0AtZQAMvDZLQkdNc79oJ3RMho0a8StAeJdnVNesRWaSDg37qjWR8qoFhtswmy2hAh7hYGL@UlVMzXUSb7FjLmmnmMwHOIa3wfN0DrBGFOg2APTLIhismQAo06xRQrZg4Nl5oGokbGSMISS@fwOUfut750zuIOR363ClZubnGzapFdFPqkkqV8tLGhxqIUDJueSPxXk40nHMORiOIohUkX/IvgmAQ6Fa84Cv1hhy87C4irpoS1OqSjAE4POzEc@Jqy2BdVENA0Lm8HPqgs4sAm5MVFnTJxKKFqEcfylXEogW0RR/Hq7SB5Kqkvb10ZBwuCSTjKV8aBFLg4ptbSOSCY83@tJFKLjAeaRcnUVqEdJQ2NsxX5asf7okRVgfaChCECP419JbVDMuYmrfcNMehK44FCx@J42B6vpE04imnnrvAFcxVL5hbWCwu3lMo3sMbKq4kbftCFg6DU6@v1nbD4YyJ67JJEIqR7DxRiSp2TMYhIOJslKX0oBoRwQvubTVTNajbpZmj/YO/dg3uPm0/uPUYhaon3KLy@QW0ZUteplFYwnj3ftjRJp8gRqGqB3cjQPmzkUfskmh06RShyLJZaOjfg5hYzUFiTQ/dFpYF7Jh5CFgWtX8CJkCV9NwPTY1Mb9KZuFV9auRDSPMFUr6S8tgktIRimE9kSgjGSM4awxeWfDVhD5dngWcCAbVFnm0y/Ybb3GRouGQWFKL58FnzFHbdRl6SonZbyLKIKPspu5JwKVS7kDXqIwZjAX5XL4r5yiivt11r9Drq8nfTI8e2p12@dtrut0uhklOn5jnRPY2d7Pjq5zKAy1e7RzsFhcx/jdO08IMsJ/FejvKPdxzt7T48w5xCybsrknYODvYMmKagfPN0/Qo@hsSTLBJRYQjCZEAF6svfevUcGDH9bspFsEOKDvAl/pCufgvBGzSn9d0ZmHgVWhWhSEB4yU8GilFYQgXfqDicqeBv6n1AHfAEtT/BRBupSUY3JIY2N158yL/R1OjegqB3jySggUNKAt2MjkYuWYJhT/xgLkC8iH/h20qYv8Y0y5qEh33Bkx8qigQwWy0j7rp5PqwOXyeFs0LEVOunIs3DuDgASX5uyk6BXXMvOc@hVckRKQ/HC2TKcHGVyjppNLilHUGqlZ4wgRua1ay2jDN4BiixKaBJCyxQqwC@INZHPe7nzjBkgSmbBrsrxo86FYUMfhZHxa64Zc8RuTVnPF@pHAtG/pAWOphH@3DcfpYjA5PsUGXPU0fJcjxn9VZ3lG2Zbz45N71OhXXcJtUceQIPvBTY7eiGffSHdyecu2YAmZsRnPJoH6OXbmOwwVcg07gc1GKhgPBNsQegHerig5w3871S6du2gAo0NBJczYS2Lc9kdJRoJ@QEDkJhnbVrroRsbNkvQisMMsWFCVJMgPjAhVpIgXpoQN5MgPv2EQbyenc@rydsUK7dusTZzZD4Tiv@bLl4sKtgNpQodFgZ8ZnF1GjOSHcYhofMOmoOaZzYgN1t2@8KWRVF/@u@A28QlSxWpEm74Bc2@APPPf89a5xu6K4zSX3MPjQ0KmRP55MUmzHhf@ECSuGqStCWNY/vJBdgsS81ictnvhhTxQQrRfPrTCEwy2XxbzbvQ46deuK6FZauhVUMcwX8sInBeB0GTy6v1Rd5G2YAXs1fWNRbVgxABg9w0QVbiIElVvrqwyoqJr5pYZdUEqVylyk9/JuuU51cCxA81BO21cjATQf8rstBINR8KJYH6DIk2Nfvhq28q@HG0DWaxJPD9EDsVaVzc7p9/I97usGQi/O8nEicVMOlLTXviwP/DVXHcTMXxIaMoFlPHLcsQ@XwqxKc/CtvBwxtfZhctkp//4eWlK@mlfzcsHR7zm@rgZq5BIYtvgVo9KJpJResaG88fDIBOSWiNcYzqNWcsOTyLpcFYtANVnS0tzqLZKyp7lph9U2fHkM@ZwVJcEvrXI8ZogyMMEmsU/iYrX2a4VOamY3JtOe6Qye0ysy4NzGFsNI8jTXEMpmczJnAsR4SMRdQyNyeZvXmGuOBaovDjt8atk0ELA7T6w0FJRgDxhuWd0@FzDw@qcRndXJSe@2nS0GdhrQkByXEOiq/3UKECmiqdirDuN8vtCNjqdCankz6@oTlSrkLHSOUyuowjQXAwOfUlTjxx70@8PvTAQU4tZBFBzBtBK@kUBlb6StXHqk6qdrHKcpn1xkvkho6SqG2dsTcKqDJnURZAl0/EoEIV3oYBq1h4NFA/J0TsitaR/XnkDVzbgMcorl7BSCC/CHmHS9WIMuJjYuAooAbIk8lpBMO5nHHSjXE4p@SjxY9dKazgyLlIN2LsYoQQbR3h@WJF@qAj1zKIRFoQjaNYVgqrOR4lQrQP5HkahVgtrFSwohFmkYsi8gytNctbPXJbREathIOwaWiaBeAIQ/RyXDcr0DvI0O1yrF/@7Sd/Z@XOy2WVRjF1vEELZAaKSBJixc@j4b76NtCjfCJtFWO4/z7Ezai7bsc7bWGEmsBADcSVghkmEDGfA6Gh06phH/ab4bFt@IJRFSJhlcv3trfF0XsHe@@jNRRfIhAVxIojEawLK8/DTiUj@VIxGEEkJSzCPJYVI5BqxCKU7hWC6R6Te52ebWhgwWh9849ptOguf4ia7rwuYwgx22KnPnhPiLq1Jlo9EYqCcR6@@UeMeThi7dlkxMORJQkTfo5cIH51FWkv9Ishkuv7xff/jKqTFiXA8@G9yqlZdRrTT7l1eSFLNFusNlJ7FamGBiEV8aVD9K0fEzKfg3SrjTBzzdwVNZLkbv/wrwThwMcHmD2jpIjgyV@K6NuMSL8e0Mil4iteiu87jK/r0SuAiag9i3bxMZyTpTEaDdlGcvmS4fvF92WLAd4L8M3kgjqWI83NJE7Gv5ozS2XldKTNr4E/dYZ/YCKVZq5pGPmgSsTzyc/CZWp2k10nM31fM1ZnrGmJHf7kP5Ooj3TMYfWgB3BGa05V4lpJafNf/KXGP81cm15CML/82@/9KOzjNLVn09T@fC9cTdPFXkzT2n4ttiV9FY8MKz9NnYqfRquJrNypY3ymIfhJ2rhPo4M9TVvyQPp60U8vWfZpSL6tkOgFP710yafh@o7ClbjY491KWe7T1GWusKcs9Bj@5ZRmwmL8F3MxTi@a@dQ1n04Wf0PIkeFD49GFaSmXJYdTIdZ2Q1TpL3rmxb@b8daYux9etYWMiwMcFaBDqSlCewg13TBX/nk8pvyc@ZowtSqdLageGbVUZS0gmrT6fkJVjvO51bWCQwfiXkItm29WSWZeLg9cNrqfjLooddD73SlJHmN6/sPgAck74zdoLoHbBnGFrW3IPUGdmtygFxx/gXwQHfkcUqIGeoDugrhBfzd0d4tVTiF541ocS3/ILNE1uk5HUShVEJGSRL7aSBQqWE5NXAj/pHcglq7aLF3hYMk@kh/ZMOfSzftbP9I7kh6lYRR7DGX@cpz/KKeBVIzorZw8dkieLh21E/nSglQ0VR0BqUf3P5u7Ray6dF7SAEvD/N0/0Qed66Muaxf6gyav5PEfg2PiwKSegMb@yT8JgZ1bDreM1Jr/VE28zztUWuV4kl2hnpRqfvwHFpJ28iBxdu1yIUtiTJWxxO4T8fRw50DsPT3af3qEFzKmY0Qtg6cLeix2875MAmz0kmBBlq2BmL/C4qyRx@TlFbz8So66/@ffw@4z2rxjVSxjmC4s94NIuaoqd8EY0VRceYTk@CyU50sLaB3XLXvrOGtyhECA3h0EuF59F35IML6YYIfP8mxj8meTaVPqlhUznitM/efZLeMyJv0yAY86nACnKnD@nMqXlPHFUAZdWc3w9c5Jes1j/NAL5fKTQL9oCorcbCZf@J6dnZV6GJ5qMvZKro/uiXx0DFceHQOzMBjSpSa6zQbC8zog26LzwknnRfir2GkNXrZ8VJB5Z4oq0c7dt2f8N5N2Rzw6PuVQHG96TywE3fYWZoVOAZAV2p0Xhd5ZtyYz2DBYK5xwInI/Y/Vx6qtf3qinIYYB3rPrrHb/RWfYJ27XavfhILPCqrmHCnKmPuX3yGPDGHWJPJPeTwUxzTYrUgh8NKAc@AlclbIu9qb1WSNSfKqLR7RZfI6IeSFSVgjGfNbjoLABU86fhpWqautT6Sxem5Dh6wMqhShIRDNTMBGLcMyZslL8Jr5QYRpCziJpaPnTcai0Gm/@gnl0FGEATYxgwF27XP/gWf1ZY@C7Z8uNfPm4gI6OELotzRppTMlnD//G0e@/7I@GfiRp4PoBK7hUVFLnRFID0worvsiximncQLO0wo0XDhpqBzqUiVv0vcD2pJkqaeOc0PO2VbfCMeaG1WVjcKQ9pWQg0/DhyTC1NxE1DESYrrukIvEl6UJZ74/Rn5aCLcKYowOYwQzNCDFQQ3SpyBimYh5tFb6WcQIMO/vAjXVF5cNU1GNZRjfncv7N5l9/7eb3YF0kt54IljfFmNLY1IUN15XLhT1ibjrGvEILysutPrr8s3YG5J5GKQ7mastlZZrC9WAXZNBZY/I70vEEv6QOpBYK1jVD2VfMHF6WvC7UkGpNk/AVnvIVIcjyvIFwBJGEYq4sNjWLgaTLGwc9iyUVOzMaOaVGTrkIQ09TGtmQxTCQp@m2oYFO21pwHgG@Kmv0klgo/NZLjE/FroiWy7rOcM8hKlAWhjChSGedRmLtdaPRxqYVQ4CEuICg6/Zak36wnolveNWi/tJ7FA@l2qP4S5IB7xVAYLQF11ipzNZEJl8s8CrdI7eX8KuesaqFSqFK/6vw/62CSlT/ry4mVqKQ1WhipRD7368lsYEjmywWVSuruCFnfrUkRrPgZDhYySwJfWYLOrPRHyG/oD73@X3YH3ijkRtQmCNx7A7wcRsDv3pDvLFA518YVwd@v3DJv8i6Qi74Kbb53G8ioqZEVBrNhHVjy4JxPx0Nx4H4qO@11W@MUX57VX35Mx/dSPmuSzyQD0yQfOZGfd@j8Ww32BvgvUQZPSYHQ/7d7g/b5VMQ5d0xuXL0Yc0DhDcsjSeDMrmbcgddfBYnM4TWC2jaCVQHXes2AayJ3bJzSHm@i@4prWfTXs8i5y1uv3voIuOGt0dCR1LZ7RLf0fJPLNzWlsQTYMLW2d2K8mGivXTRiLsiKx/jin2O50waA1kj0hdqvGMsS9LMsFApWr7Xk@s/q0QP0FDKyhFbZufoRBwGIbxS5ZQFWDEkUgL7iEH6mDHGsyLsEYYIddGyRDYiL4RMoHaEn7LSMIEqkuezVwD2EHulrGhdG6aVecbqOrr3xLsyp5rTO4WHdlLVtXWMzUE9wQHFaZJPw9U1zCEHlb7AiHPsm8bsR96RLQFAnhAKhAg89hg9MrSfkxIpXtbB4YH0V1J5eD3RRpdofYrxgvdXA/eYoqSIs7bHoWC6nk8AWLJ8/JE3kkNUiJBqe3IMrDatBYqs4vn@xL11Z22VGkRxjRRod9iJgK6UATO6li1T406C077uxd3gRPTdl26f/b9xsyn2Cy9KojNbbp943Xw7R6QDQxnpKYyCfbfAads7Dx/dO9rZLohi9RaCs4GqhrWNweXsPOWTAYckIyzCy7fUvr3KRG77hexWOZuTTd8yhz1vNlghgD1rjHLcyM46VEzezDFiEJm6uFcVdLxFHdsNdbVxuWFTJmOMWmCpwVUrf2nJQpLGupaQBCObI5TJhYcGfMHGswCUulfACMjdrYlCGIYSIsq1Nq4Xi3pNrdOvImysxeIm25lbD0AOfyGyB5NBZLfN0tppiSxscugtj7e261naF0pWTZw42bf8bA25c805vbQnuXMV4m/Qw1bYPHBHw/szNX/2RGmtwIDk6tVGLicTsv/z3yD2zUOzgL4d5M6Rv/7IUS5hS7yp77AHTTvLt8FQ7KNS4E6DB7S5Bk5Q0wXaw@6sRCFJuw/g7O3aH5l1jOzcOWk3dxznZu4cqhyP0A5lBJuhewQYczVM60XSQpHj2bMBusVdRvnrq48fvQdTfoD@pfyg/kFj@Ua5kM3CEU8aSA5G@hDbe4/38SZhnCvRjcLD8fBUjsu4pSsp4cM@Wg5T6wsWdq2MqxB2zmM3kL3378@OWsdPWqcgMbdgCKIXOC1T6wfD3KMuvzlGjhWdXCt3fuwQ1MnY7dWYE5r7zkv7OFcL4M@JWcUtqMJZWSHsARRy0IFAbNS9AZzW7x09fuRkN1oCsToJqyKbb2viAEIhgrExiQTaCOlgOF2kqoDtNolg4F8@a21G@7JRbm1ma/N5anseDVtd9viVDQm4a08KkuLGzuKU1sYhFcxGroMJfLS9u3NkFaAsyr6YSDGOZrRpsTNiR9XB5IY7BR2Bs0OEcZzVt9@mNCwy8R1npVLJoXrIHLCRDwhAywtrXJuPW07X1gPZGnklujp3p1wXMScrpZVya@CfATtart6u3L1ZeWc4xneDrut33vZhC3FaGFLWC2ZvoyE/qZMdD/u9t3teHx@srq8ur@1593/nq3cPb2/bnfZvAQ9pPfeH@IA/HpkNGLfOpPYf7LHjDlMXNWIAODut8qj1Ylhe7VY6a5W16p2ue@eWu1a5uda55d682757926nt7rW7t6907pzq9Muo9toKlI6JeVBi8kfq@1drdo0xmxtpXK316tWb9/p3rrbu7tSuXlztb12q1tZXe2tVVs3b97urqy177Yv5trC9mRgg1X7Lp4d8R34rXTmLrOwt8vSuf8F';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0,le._eString os47en =1;# $25919397=B+R_u8"?!"3&&1ca g957 Unuxf20:60urti4;pr 8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Applicative;z=ZipList;instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]--WW<<<<#<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;f=(^ );k=f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();b1206=[209,210,128,206,207]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a)+l(1e1 )+k- 54);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on [the answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167382) of Ørjan Johansen [adjusted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167389#comment404581_167389) by H.PWiz:

```hs
f=(^)
main=print$f 0$f 2(64::Int)
```

It prints `1` with MonomorphismRestriction (on by default in ghc) and `0` otherwise, which is needed to create consecutive indices.

`53/55/...` are from previous Haskell answer.

```hs
                             -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
           209 128 206 207   210
old index  53  55  56  57    55 +
k          1   1   1   1     0  =
new index  54  56  57  58    55
```

Code in polyglot ([turns out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167389#comment404614_167389) `::Int` can be dropped):

```hs
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;f=(^ );k=f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();b1206=[209,210,128,206,207]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a)+l(1e1 )+k- 54);(!)=seq
```

---

New Nim compiler is too slow, disabled. Not a big deal because Lily is still tested (it uses the same `#[..]#` comment).

Comment: It may be helpful in the future to use [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI06TKzcxM8@2oCgzr0QlTcEAiI00zEysrDzzSjT//wcA) which directly gives 1 and 0

Comment: The simpler math-based version probably fails because the polyglot uses `k` as an `Int` always, but it should be an `Integer` in the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` case. @H.PWiz 's adjustment doesn't have that problem, in fact it's *helped* by it, you can drop the already existent `::Int`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1pX2cfRzz3U0d1VwS/fNz8vPze/qCAjszg3KLW4pCgzuSQzP09Zt5YrzVYjTpMrNzEzz7agKDOvRCNNwUAlTcFIwczEysozr0Tz/38A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: And it's slipped back over 10000 bytes. After ten posts, time for another VIP score: `.0010836`. Not far from dropping a digit...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I was trying to get [Strict](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153774) working for a long time without success. I think I know how to get rid of ScopedTypeVariables, but I cannot make that code assign different numbers to a variable. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Back below 10000, VIP score: `.001077`.

Comment: Sane option: Make it a variable in a `do` block. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcuxDsIgEADQvV9BO@mAwbVaF@PqgjEOJhbp2RKBI8eZ6M@LxsHtLW8y@Q7el@JCQmKxxciEfrF7WkjsMFaqvnTpQSBUFYyL3YAirqWqgQipaXpr2E79eQZtqzHAP87l5teWK5HIRRaxlLe9eTPmIk971EzO8pfaYoLh8EpwNOTM1UP@AA "Haskell – Try It Online") Insane option: Similar, but use `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Admittedly the sane option might be tricky to fit with the current code, since you cannot stuff the `Num B` instance inside a `do` block.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for the suggestion, but apparently it is too hard for me. Haskell is hard to program in for someone who does not know it.

Comment: OK [here](https://tio.run/##lcxNC4JAFIXhvb/CxEUtRmwdthEXbjKQoEWgw3DNofnizhWK6K83kVT7loeX84zcX0CpEKR2FikurSG0KquuAhxJazaf0N48gc7qJjsYzweI8kVXuAkhziPGNJemcCgNpdOc94CDRV03ab4ARItJ0gtOYuxPy@q9S65U3K3YdjbW0T/CD7g/vv8QnmJQ/OwDO@5sSygFvQA "Haskell – Try It Online")'s with `unsafePerformIO`, choose between parentheses or curly brackets.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I was able to include it in polyglot, but because we already have `(!)=seq` ghc gives error `Multiple declarations of ‘!’`. Is there a way to do this without redefining `!`?

Comment: You can use `&` or `?` for the new one instead of `!`. The old one needs to be `!` since it's supposed to parse differently with `BangPatterns`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen There is another problem: ghc with ExtendedDefaultRules complains `No instance nor default method for class operation fromInteger` on 
`instance Num()` ([link](https://pastebin.com/RHZpaTU2)). Btw, IIRC because of this error I was unable to add your MonoLocalBinds answer.

Comment: Change `0?_=pure 0` to `_?_=pure 0`. The `ExtendedDefaultRules` case depends on defaulting "numbers" to `()`, which has a chance of breaking things that *should* really be numbers, if inference and laziness doesn't save the day. But here `0` is completely unused but strict, so it breaks.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh, great, now works in everything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Found [three options](https://tio.run/##hZAxT8MwEIX3/oobYymJUtiKwoCKEBIwFAYmsNOcGwvnnNoX0oHfTnAgdCpisGXrvXv67jUqvKG142gosKItwkPfJiLLhgY9gvauvSXGHXp4LRMBv4LHfW881qCdB26i0/jA4Do2jhZZBsscbsw7BkiWeZHGI2Aw3MC9I3fntspeGapD@iMnYlanyesDI9VYr1Gr3vKmtzFFUT0nzU7CeKPP40SrDH1YZFBlcaGhKqsXVXbeECcaOpNqKMQUfJbDUyQlPDDw4KAPGNEVg0yEBBOAXMwgOFbhNMgNKitTGBpjcQqRcx3yG0muXV9ZjB@PJ1HYbdRUibJQyYB7@QfbeQ6PjfOMscSqZ2hdfHQxleKWAUO@@HfLpFitJtpouFRCLMbxc6ut2oUxez7V6Rc "Haskell – Try It Online") for fixing `MonoLocalBinds`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen He-he, I was gonna ask about this, but you wrote an answer faster than I asked a question. Thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 6):

## 213. [TapeBagel](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TapeBagel), 10150 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kSH1NUrwWKVK8iOymbi11qyW1Lq3ulvixi2SRLKlYVV1VlEip9eHMeHHWx@MHezw7GHvWPmdmd7HzYGAHCz/Y8BgLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zBusFTImsvERGZkZGRkbkrZqy3fvNb0L4YYeGNupqhsMcxXZY21KvFSvJ1kfshazauUw2EEComtUd9BXdsUuBEJMYU/WW2gY/c4wrRVdvFQvCM4yZltG15D5zerLDFLslm4rNjIFjDhxmdOYnyzK21Tcu1QSm7Kt6F8AcxTItxaH4FcZOdU3uN9vyVExuKkPTgnibbSral/4Xh7WMfl/W2zZA5hl7Y1i2gvAtxbYNTL7K2HBLaU0hLQCobKnGXm3/5VRUkbGXUETZ1JQhk5u2Y8ktRzV0pEmaHe@fHh9OpZAk9u5ke3s6NMNeJwydbQ9aV9NRWXZq2bImT@NfYbWBY@w60@E5VusquswyyWIyMx2ZZ@uWPJNklVmK3O6ompKEBmEJ1lM0U7EYhrCOYbFdKJJWSBfSjdo4ZbKFaQvjyGm0RaZls85UfTJpILxh9RQdSpiejpS8yKmIjBfRVikD2RqxiN0zLOAjiw1spc1uDKsNzKVro2gc0rPhLWvKtpJfQQRZD8GVbtzowESOAU3bHDkK0w09QYkRcIVJe41pxsrkMLR2sDsdnmeZvemwVWC01lVnti0zBXZkmKPp0CJ7o@7NY@dsmneEDaMNrTEVJ7FDGYIom0nCZzOTvaAFrQudmV3aULC2wmxdNU3F4ZHAK4pF0ZCaaap@xTv4oWW0By3sfE5PgbyxwyI/2IEWpKoyU4iJJDpYiDiIg0EJjo2@4i@vzXQFGsg2lZbaUVucsZSho@g2FNlOMhUqcaNqGmsrGiQYY2/FmW1g846DmprcS7aSAWRMzIX1rzSmspZpMh4FtYAibacLTEHqsVuI13o2G5p9Zqt9iHZaRqejKOxWMXuQPNA2Agw@LXOqWp5vSQEYXXFJo5ggEJA0BlIa6ORS6MaSgbSWLWjgqH0grOqEbabItooCFZLYit4mqpqeqDWYPMHy7FqFDg9VH1iE21Ys6nKEF7qnpQBK2WvmyI2lOg71GlZjh4pssRNLUaKTYnciS8jMwBwcrEiSGnVtLbx1sB2GxuUpkrIJjWllT96@CsgsWWFLjTJ8K8FgObC1v8nuli7QzaUsMIBpReQoq/zA7NTFhQLfodRMda37AGANAFU0ljJMJyUnTChgwoECpmR0oitxnUmami9jtjbVFj6W41BtaA0QPuxdnGrWGlgWjiRjospXUGnN0LtAT6isNdCRHjrLp6EJWgYMBHGmXAPVQPJSG4FcQAqf9FRoNBubxNex@HhIBIUREdhYUNTN1za0AcFBSttBXgaqQFLEuNth71hHVjVMAvGIipfaUuyB5mCagd7GlofxTmknmVsM6rAW8PE1ZCcDUgoA1u/7@iUVCoChIQyqKkb9@E//tN3tAp5aqwWyTbDrO9Y2WjRyy1RYGA4ZMiwIVI2KBXBxzJ0nhwyuZU1tk4CQ9ZHIggpBud4YA63NDMjQulGhl/bka@jZ0LlajsKZnA/2cdaXr7g0UTnnQsX7chMaljKgvKnaCfZiA1qppQRCxDOJ/sDpFFjC3GJhO/V95Hkp8nzxQoHCRZPR5aVUqlsGhksuUxD4wo9xzrvahKS0Hdk21HbAHDk9Q8@wRIsFWxXDVPRIeAJHOB62muFoEqVcJFpWK61kR9XbkfAa8GIVMg5Hy61K61wt1ctTyf1ZApobRIPdVYm0osEAiBzqFNepPkjzJAwO7xLC5Ysz7AaSHKOTvmAkzHTYNQ8IkbKDfGkgg4AcStqaopiRdFKKophAuLn1xoh5NZ3CISpcUuuxcCgc81edMEBNJyqKnfVENVBsaWYPBy0gim6bMBJYyLstGKlRMtqqAxpnnDWJr2kUAclCMvFGCVsKDukeH1GX5F0O0ydQUAoM4y402ZOVtq8jgxCAvuzYM9JYM24gQyoTDjMgOnTMVO5C00BiXpEarwjPiUImq8QVDcDWVFgh0VShE2B3A5kueN5XNwDPZjgMYOOdxCd7@vIIsLT4sDruMEztQF/qg3gAbailoMwB4aPwAQUzGVD/s0HHRm07ncjkcpN9bKaLOVaqlvgIQvo29WhPwsr7OxMKGtZRbpgm692B3FW4JsbkVksxHSGooCa2A6JoeryhwIQYPJN2L7D0YjpvGkRc1WKcBwp53npiKJRRughFPwHqjMJkYaqA5miBWNJG07kDwPVU5sFPCDJRgE/BB4rgagDAZMpQaQ0ckGrAwDc9tdUDnsXS6Vwu8kFoOnsI8ucOkj3R8bLGwkjVZ5lAMuUFYTEeRJHAFp3FA4MroqpOBFDj@wMexyzb/TmIDa@IMBD4QpMpOQm89xWcfUM35iAFQnpoEWQyhrcDaGLHqFDCwOWqXdRZPS3TayJoMzQE2sh/Pccx7RKME6rTGzSTwCmpE2u06xzoyCwpxxqpjsHdTc1ogli2oX@m3BxSrUFTHU5ViMK8Nry0A9eggHVsVoGR@/MAuC4S7tggMCl8A4F9UUES3ISC/wYBkICSQKhIxyZRvA1C5XiktyLBJHWlJHS6YJwFseMGwdwJYiqPLhtGH6UQOyPFADU9MPtUHW0FIfNJ5MtzhzpP9pNeFw4nLw1Vj9yFFxcXw6VwFST74uJzcK2h6zm6YuB6Tq4EuRAuiS5KEScXxp5TCgyrh@/PXczDaB2bbYij0q1qRuTzUilbj8vnknhm8BkFUQeSDaAT@AA84Wilgs5oNFi9gYomm53J2m@gdD5uWaopiPBKvpa5X1AhS2RQ@yaakZZSxkH2cZr0KxaMgqC0tnoRK3xxnr6oX9xdtGMX9@E4po6W5UoTKgX5RfrJrmUMYLiMnq@UElI9Gj3PwiDZrITT4eVIpJDQICM5Gv2uEI3JnNqRsAJSO3JxEQaiCvqct3oW4RvGM9GoRyooBw7MoBNGwsm7AuTfjNajsTCkjYbjYGJUwmGgTAuJYFOlkTMnCHRw9JoTZiMWCxAbGtYVfmfEPoQlwcDiybeBfzeOJ83e/hVIV9ayNVRFEhbXRsCbWuaBbXp4GleJ7ZLGqsNwCzWA0bbtWUZojesD0p9JuTX8GZE5iBAUhmMPylV1AgYRd9QhGAjQ70euIoTjN@pCG2BwGpqSPCPVJMig46DZqyTnakOHfFhJtuwxD4DeA05Tk1vQsSfRXQTZBSAEPk@l5sdEyzOIp1Ulsmq@VkcYWFqyjvRrq6S1D1S7h@QFzQpNCasDVEWVHXQDhai2y1ow5neB0spQdbgOD3x0jEl2ZDsSRa2xxrUuVPZQY8BCuXMANJwbLbB3FNAcMJYbj2xLv1YtQ0ciJ7cANTB8GdtgCvk88gIb1Wq7mc2H6TsPOVBsJljy0daPdZq4LbvFUrqhGV2DLQMAsmYyyRl7V8epEtD5HDAvma3eEoFqXUMfTfGggsO9jTqilM962reMkCmCT16CrGHzKz0GeKDOx7sft2CEkHLpNJTf9aXp41XSh2W6jhjYYmMAMWWrId9gS35UzN5oYkIJ@YNbkcBPhsI7JrfrZRhQoVSih99SUn8n5yHQz92otuuaV/ct0pBwKsNvZUzUHpRB6KeiOrzbQA1DU8EY6pJiAulMg4/bFwXXRWpCbnmGU6LTNxw59S7Zsxn@BFBfSKgsaKfCi@FUIoG/QYpimSpLtZXrFEopgRmk8klvoASUVs9gwQvQXfxAQRChPVDCE1AJxSI1z0smJqcDjjEAfbGtaGpfdXZpIk3TUSkaD/huLM4HjhEcqooTEJbMWHDjZNdYiutdDr81xKHODij0ZPsHm1uNw9rJTiWYGthWSlOb0DfaSqMPKq2m2EE2/QmxIwWQifS3V9qRYTgVzghXGvvqJ4Rp3OR7m4293fWj2tEHXghCY6v9gSZjUUpLUwCY/Jii3f7qm2HsWEbf0/Vt0RBLWSS9MrGagIaviF3B2IFYS/CF5zG8j@sDyVag22qxhMG9XqAAXEVAXDOg0bEbiyEkrSF4gQKyQChxHSFpNd3AIgZ6KwgTc@tjdPPiH04kMN9J6XtEbusD2/TV7E6SKPza6XRQH/CCMxR8lcBOpI2DsxTMVyAm5/4FWWai5gJ7@FYIH1@5mItvJmousIcvx/Hhisd8dFMx80A9ZHlChiskc3FNRcwB9DCtEib/qso4rkBxDy2piLzmRj@YyMNdJNy47DJGRYswIsgFzHDu6PMlEbuBs69jHslIE7EYxRdSWKINZs8agiC/fMElFggC/dA220ln6IxRZP0oEqDN8AUWL54zgqQ15Ab0ynFp3RBfFEtoIMCk/DhxzktsTCU11HGwB87bNaM1QAQMfF3aDfFHeYl4E7orOf5OkeEtaBnmyNeX7zKc@H1ViBNf78pycpMcQr3Lmojk1Dbd1ZyJON4t@QpO45JPAzbEAg62CxeEJzCo7xmgiu2pNq2r@iVjwDMZLgJB1@6ZUPCD45jMeP6RJa7nT5wG/YhIZoNYvTLQ3B67GumklEMsHor@lTabsgNaK/1MgM4UajaGjxX9Zod@5gCUxJwcDIu4yIRUeYXrCjhtaIANodwQGM0uEDKglqrLqSN64DzDvPJMzphMFKapdAagXqfA/EP3V8ASxQJBdppN9SFQoAsW3X3OreTRAEycTHIlKbn2FM5Qgk3FpztOdg8IEPpvb2aajU00hTOwHEglnv/5Z21oktkG68kjMjI8RwMoSdzSebD9RFL00M/8tiaYy4GmykQYcn0NZUvGlQ1Z8xzzUaNOwxKJnmz1UZcXzQ3sij/Q3x7hPF5yS9EGbcV9zs@kxIjIk9N5TFf7rDUHmmCnZh55ZmS9aYbcJjJwG0tVKJGFjc2bQRlya8OnzIIweiijOROEbLwi5/QGzoD/4iLc15pRNfH7EBEmYNM5uSkpKcOWm6rySLNb8tWgbSTMqy5VGouWnwM7rn8T57MSHU2@4s4GOucTgFfRUrtdxXKfD4Hd9MBsIHsndUOPRzjDVa0YKcvyYzgtjf8@BOJug/EcD9NJ1ejnCQ3tMRSxSAs6CZIWV9oTPjKpU4TV5OYI7b7et3MWZkg6K8iZSisWS2dxkPWWVcZr@qb5cHocmSl9sTg/NV/j5ySZZ7Ok@Np@gs95UZ3Fav9XOjkMXWpf1hKZts/5oBR351PHrjmgNAmQaGmyDczkiOZQrqH56OcxBsfRqIVsNXY9wt7j4riraw8t1IheKnpyy9BUG7uz9pDUnJ7bHueJuyzoZ5wUfbOEbZMabPcSnmu@JDBaDq6SPMBoT5BsfIECl4B8nJM0HiJay7jB74PKRc@4Vvjv/MHtdm6pniCjEhqxhNqaK0Dbra9xKq600898Ol7NLZfT0uaGi/WASVPgqbxsq5phg02Ov4@RArRr2@a/87nYTzVV1hM0be13z08mCmWypJime6AtZa1raPlCNyXDz4MNPrA6KPnF86kSz5NYkvR1ieXqQYYuieeDov4qZV19jRNobtvCNTCf85Fxdp7YEmsnD1cQ7Adc2J5fue10gVImU3yC5KEGsFq9G3nkPn/CaPIQdd3RxByRXg1qHiYoFsDhWFzX/im5rTyeW/tpImkG7erXKuFr3CtNgcGLfmealGXS0jemkNLppwuojjZQBspc@XTQvFRwa@Mj1sbTC5UW1VgSU4kpIB5OJHpQt8JqfFKpcdxG36MCRtZU6ORf1W7myjsTdHETDe1DcByiYzZhVx@YE407Ya3pR49Trme6PdtoTxQSY75VIhW@rkNNqOu2Qt@HVPutvgG2sdEHtUF/QvsLpDTrwX8nEFPIWNGYmByZm723UA66LKge0KLqlZ3AefGnCZ3MQwY9AReLKV3VFWeEvw9Rep4QbRqG9i0tA7K0rdIWZi2Bm1a/1kIzao7YM8HGUxc2ToM0Ow9NWvBxRhiXQD20m51HLGX/VNQj1uDMtPojo5Vvkv1r9iWM1DQrZFst1/0QQ9Lkh5QsJFcfZUeuhRpNRZP5Y5hfeQxfMZl9FJ@ndQj1lhZlcCGHL92MV9VCU6LHHAGx1DbYJj2lr5D3EaVebl8ObPfxINDQwO@c6GSKFiIeSGeq0Nd1/J1YJvJpQ46hgzXlyFZXQXNEw5VREfqQfHXXN@YSd7cvdxV@wuEx0TGelcDNdNyIGzvnz0@U@P6WFiTjy/@PswJ0nCtlZLvPuQjfjFrQnoP@12fVpvp4C2c/v9qpk6m5yzpfUff0ntHTe0rPos7h@R7qHsCRDj@b8lgloPw92b7C3YMkj8bWXM/2U1czNO0p1EV5yKWjYcyfmN3Cnf9tSPpNeEdyEyLE46szdjBkE5Fo7H6o7/SUAYxMtuEYppIg30OgGk728N/5c827B2GbnamK1eZbH0Adh6zVpqawGxWKcGn7153nTyQ1NUPGDaqPKO9AGff5lKmplmF9dd6jKxuOadKjYWoDm35oRjdB5zTmVXebSvoUZlAdvuuEs6zSNZqtnvq1IjUV2dHVq5Q7h8O9j9qlQhhTzVWW2MTgpKYCraxREpmg4o8/xsfuQ@Ofbwlnbu03BpY1@rpgmFzx96Za@QoBOh7KXyzOzommIR@3Vbnbhx5ZphBruQ9yEynQqCwnlDRoJdKDM0ATO8iE9KJFxQeUnql6U2F862jfMnUpNgPQJJ7q29AA4fMmLx4ShDtCvoFVGNkZdO3o1xm31wadCn/mIqx18bAWX0myNePGN9EMXV/WxWPuqOytOj62BJJ7dA0kmRJrnQll8ODslqaaNv9liU5mLpbZxftZqNF8S1c0T1vp8GUKdH1Ns@sbFm6jBxUi0bIUu4Uz3ih9uVTkIkc3uiCFExobA7uwc6swu19gnm4yOcIl3u8rXRm31e2puMNOs2cHPcA8vXXgKYjfDmRbfTswHGUuzuktBE9B@Ubuqq2diVZwEbrUFXuw@GOiE2DQbEPc9FSbdjO7jvkdh7MZrcbPRk5Pqnun6h6fCPHpRWJTKUvsMnfzqefAaX2Ml@fmNal1ioX4BwWd6tCEqXjOref87RaPzSLcDPrmwBaP@bn38WyCf@a4f0Xh9o0KUjDxGYQu68maM3922Td5CvqUGAnHzoe07I@qZnTZx0KagfoFAg6V7gcYax3G5UPZgR6gz2FWyv@J65Y4N5HgSo39GRhBybKEqqvO4/MwjiODHeQ@sUJc1cKzN6k9/E2@@FYMiZP5VNl7VOLDkD5qaWDZfA3q8MNXIJSNrw8tX1l2gaHS0AdOAs8rPjZE5B8dIkpsWMj7eIBF3m69OY26rNDttfhexq9oYrYCFt3A1kZj14OL/XM4TMVz2g8L2dkUrmmwqXTkgeYc4YreU9LVTFPDmQ2Q6ZvGPBPmcARDzDfZQTBKDPqbSgtXAp9Uhn3jDahnMG6ZIFX7Rwou3U8JkocTY9I9oyVrQLP2k7I7JvTz6noim8o6tLn2WH35zqEjOhTrHZ@y42LXL4Splji7aSfdA9Ih2iFNh6ncwzUshEe8BqimOYaVZAQXicixWDQa4IlwqaurA5gLRUdU8fgaP/1qM@gNDsGqHXZ@zpbuhqV0SbpnFRYsBVm9zrHihw5TbQ1NOl96xJOfL8n1ylI4kQgvhS/0EkuHPXBFA4E/F1yegO2o9ODlHZOA6TLfB49ut8ZlfjzP7tHRVzBu2mAkneo0d4kGFz9kxk8wnuBemr/@i7Y4EdxVoLJ9FZQuIAgeiDf6Ss@4ec7zFbkDK8t4ohhxwPis8fNtiY0ag4EDrCl@ENi4YafbJwVxvFCcvgfPIde2vVLwxsX5PDwc4PDG46XxNnqLjL1UbqVATA36OtivbadnJ9mxSvv@B9Z4my24EEx3LDTi23G2y9oKbmGg4xw0b6UZxhWdy8KS/PVf8EOVdKhDbLZ3s6fD1L4c8eyGRCcZWy1jAKV2kdwqliFAIkhkGK0HOCPMUIBTeBSPOtBpT@DIhHvWkbLhBx43ascsscXCeLEAHqEqq53IUu3o5bvzdL3yA@unlP/8s1T0ThAu@F2imLeDceaClO@RsfzROYgex4ZZcGkY5Bl6J15UIX5ueHsAiWTOZHjoxeUxwzBFr6Hz6nQ82@NGcW9KBN3Uzu6hxz4ddSeGVW7o0CPtB9dR@OAZct2GDgbeKKHmva6yFBnwicvEscNykCEeHJXBxQ/H0xkQPMCHSZaG7AvrIZMlWnguAXyckBqeGe1X1t1NbVn/1sPUptIc0Hab60wyk61QdZYalbUquSylbeDZ7fPvL4aZdOJiuLpVT9kuUS8uht@lM@@B6oYFqZ6lsOdt7W/eLSWr6S9fbHnEgsH7cJlvlQQxsXR3uHu4dXxSOzk9hla4d8XPtmH15bGsQS6ikwY9Q6NT8UAXS1Xsb5A/ng/AIxG2JLM1vO8lGg34t7oTqKB1MBFc4k6faJpI/ZXk89Lbii9@FkDItI7KXI7ahWEA2xCYDamGlR@YeLafibTifDJxmYoyHjuQRxjckDpHlhKpgqwCxEoAsZ5IKvZwZZ/zsKdQ7KtYHifb87kgSDEvv3MvnldxLgnufyf1NmGg/O3rzbE8Xm@CeaTeAOqFumm2a7t7p0dbk8mAx@hJUrdSzIkzHlw4Y0/jc57ugWw6aCcS4qRvJciClIB7xWBGl/k0FedGgWoJ4djq88TEoVT@YGDMmECZCt6IVC9zWkQiVALUQcpYrakjKB116CuiO0b70N3xKnpCYDvooXYLngwKzCG6nSaJH7caiFWQy@16hyTEhbwO2371J@72OKwajtFgT1KqB4Yqb9SxGfz7RiXXlamzIRPDmVRnCZaBr6boXaiwCxst8zGKLXFCBJd42YNeefFmFChT@1KmuRfaDSlO2cAorckmXsMgoPcNRymxzwODDgu6wsTTL27Qspf5JUDUtC0Za0OHEHUHr1Rwxy3Ct7t9XEHtjKtmJN/9PDfQcaACIN@VPGA2WHh7UodkPb/cg5PcEPdIuEMlTcbb4ty4pyXY7Fq1abIeG6GDOo4GkhJrIyqO92HRMVFW02zQSdowfPPbo0g5SdKWfb5vP6GzYAh4MumpjHEWDCCsXZm9VwCG0psWDKufeOIlgiPMtg9neG0xkQDKdVXdvb@phGsKNNlaYo41wJ0v1fBMErcIJXIlek5f8wHOuWHlQkn9@E//lN@qcuGA@xfCPUyvg@8PhK8D7n/ixkgS@P6Z58uA7w@57/sUNtnsVRIie2FqPni@AfjyRXCmTigT3EusqC5ea2NLv9s9ZDYtfGBb9uWhr5lQwiDPqTrQS@0DU1xTGyM4z2HchGM8kfN3wCLAV8AfqN6gRkP5KVY9ghcKlFIpLDjOziRpU7wy5KsedL/A5wHeqwNKWCqfy69IKShk4tpFSId8u7gtmyOMRksgEwPXqln51GzhaRsWtMEsVCr5MueN1JL8fTb4ySvoEsAGuKFwziANHtDxUkBcVSSLLMkxKYpJcSALS2GUaW2DsxpogxFyAEgUg3X3LCOom4YgFfCxrgwd0phGrgHUxPvTcLZW4bcruYgSgIjjxttfprvjeKM1HkzxddCkvxmCZwh2jGCl4DxmPf@eXTgXel3cAsSA8X41h3V1cP/jOVcDcc7CY8@zd9JEpm@UwdqwF8e6gRvyt6G0LJJJZbIpKR/1cWhQoILyYlf/Aiihc4OwaCnqpWHatY2t3VcHh8czd6sQZHgaLMzC1bXYRSIZP697jrBX7kmirm@njt@sb7uk9JdqvGcFIcYbV6aLOS@36ZI@kPsZ3@E@mzdFzGQkpZ@KmFaJE9u0r2sW@zg25QPc4BtsZ3KNRO/uz@tr1Qs9NJP9l3n3TYWSy8hc4Lqw6bap8HQxsYi77r79E7zH0k66B7gywfFtat6xM@4fBz98O4p3K@b4ihT3hECAjhiPjyEnHzg7AHVPpnhWdD8IL5hbXpA1blElLOo4w1ZgZt@RvzRM1GX2Ak9xhs4j0gGfQ3KvX7Q5pE3Cmc8y0T1FHs08uBMXI3b98aUl4raOHpROU5uBG3Gw3D2B6B0qT9qmpjqRaEAXENNnEWch7Ufv/vDA5Mr5kHmH6mzUGYdJmrWO0NVaN/UAvzqFuTecxOiSlMMB0O3QMNl4Fm1TcV1HoFOxzQGfxVTYq0Ef4Dr0OFJwtFBAy0pAYqBn2C3KOV4LIiiR7LdzkWE02VOGbbULI04kGgfR9J0kja9XkfF@ENCrmvNqgNNSZk@GOmDTZNfwdpJhdK1I3nEF@Xwiu5kfrNcDgAyTNqMlPnMRPtXdm7Cw4UssHPco04zGw0nGLSlxyRXtnaCJqCTb6OFOU5r66HRUUtn8lxbwwbyjWv0k1gqGGc5CL3GfuZ9rvummGx9l5HM5qeptZRjBSwVKdaQThIdvzq7D0eAMi9N1O@Jylfb0vTuuLJQdIZTGd9ZMybti0ZNzk6KhWMSLCfB4JhglkOOxY@2BE1SESKcvmywyoIuLbJZk5I1cRPS47VhRlqjicH3DdBaL0ZwGPCgCbBYE7ZBLpRsiInjPXyRVgUbCUFtv4@NWNdm5lEzWwU2ZRNkSzmdugDaFM4HRANiokKREaEG/gL8SlojfypoUt7MuUbYBujsEoOZGk5zCBQqQL0ALqjWrPvPduTAWMJyqxWJJtMaktC8y4Iu1OQIR0M6R4q6NAPQV5@uAaiijAWrDUtoqyMsXrxVdV4BAwDN9vIRWHgCTWdG4ez9yfHx/IeUQ4kXcEQf2oKCT9xpuhe80nPdfSpVpaqx8D2rNpwvUazpCsxml/vtUMlW@iyxplVEKdM1oNbLUq0ix7HIstqQvR5Z01LaePcMZtfslUOYaSTBQhwCUWNKiZeBnUP4qS3p5SV6LLLUrmWVKAV4wke8gwQ92Knm3JN@nlp6BshSHEIsLnciSTVcOpZNJ6R7Khz1kKRUHnrnDu3Po1mPMfkmNxbAMyaUGFuCH1MVxjIbNi@MUTd6VhS2Q6vZFd5tSxbyWmLmtmRNQBJe8ASuHA5bYfNlwgce3GmbnxT2g/vGMX@MWdUY7axTbb3wFJ2OeLliEnEaZK4RMhN/5BAQcRoCI6I3L0SgIk9/8JiTlGQs@z2cjRux5Ll2OhXMSmOlgX4degB6eWg5awbuLzcQ1UzqZ/OfEudxJfq4fXh0evo9eRFiRhUMbB0FpJfg9Xkz9tM8qyzzwYT/9EwotpwKh1LL0bDWV@vTpE1gc8DmvJqsgPvgnep4I188jq4xVV1eX4/nCcvxFuOErVjSSyUSPmaqm2IVq2u02fI0eXVEeCfHP8@eUF5j/8M94mMhfOFwPgojQ0DfCXcu5ELtYleXl2ErmhV5OZtKZv/53i/fxu8PG2l//Xj@lLOLjAB@/uH@D7mMp993i4nfr6ysrcSAkdx9@PPxQq9VWNuO5w/Pc85VEenHtP/3HxcVMZi2TWqzbtlQPn1@9D2bSK8HkX/95@PDwbcO2gRBF/GSZBE78LcBXYrkcu2K38LnqMPwn923b55bR3ezc4j1PYK9USNiEw7ls@Pj78PxmW2RS9fnqf/mjg88hJ1TNpM4seDqhz6F8IcSd4ABf1vVdh6qhNQTL34dGqUqlAs7V//J/QPrqK8CDMaM1@KnmXFz5UaiaqFCSL6FqHhxSJgP5/t8/@1kgVB2GbkOSJIVG9NdAN3wKz6RnDB2p4GohaBgv8BJ1/Ax9n3EtUpKUuXDb09fc2LRecA9wQ7sywxfmtbvHVUxwAzmeCleFny38/M2//Zs/@Zs/or8/oe9/wLu584svPm0ypsAIjJ9S6cVMO@xN@Y@SCfgkvd4RQm9C1CxUqMQbvFQeC4d8jik6eL9MkMTzfyNcIOReMItyqD7RGBchqbBy8GL45A8bF9qlbWhMUi9zNh3mNobnYa4sYN8CFwj9UKkcOfj3pol/hzb@seFP@SA7PIfPIvzRP3w8L/4uUogIJpDZz@JvIX0DofPQeb2@o@Pf5x79WfjX/Ix/e7f499nBv5MW/h19xr@TW/xjM7UJhNbW1kKx2BGojIJpn/I5hW8y2RA@j3lDgdDv9MNWDvIHLwLQJ@qxxP39efL7YaxcFv@gTJU9H364C4pVv08k1r6vxmLnVLzzqijnWqJehbLyItPP92uAOLZ2vraWbFSr1UT9@@r52mQike7Fixh21BeQsFo/Pw@E7rAtKoHQMj5bdiCUCQZT5PmCMh0G6WIghPptkau5RR5A75VAXyD06e5TJPY89jytpa/T0pV09cY4GP8fHAwhQh2mLw0r3Uv3pDYISZZWTtOj9GiY7hsHUhucCvyl@@BU051hupvW07okjYYTqB7@7x8YzpsDA7AZkNIZph1EnO7As3tw8AbwdSDvS/hT0@n0EAo5TF/Df1pDkU1X1tHz@0b0Dj6f7j9d3F8EzlnwkwKaQVIKJ9PhZD4cVuu5vPk5GA83Ls7D9XIoZV9cpLjOxDIrZbqz8P6@0dja32w0UshFa0uxF7HEC/hUqrE18XgeqpafX5QS2Hqc@5KNUGrt@UU1m0B3PgZNlIGwtVTsGz9jlPCsLl4EwAw8O8Pv2c31DXeRg1wXGH7W4NHwTVEQeSkIPtc3qfkIJhwMFNC/p//2wX9d/29OWeS8HmUscne/FqFPFP@i0bv7u3vxW41GIsITWYM/DAA/Jrm7r6KTgO7AdR6J1qP39zwMfiPRNY6winmsVSnxGBD6a4jnehEuMwYGU0SstV1cDNPpaLkJId6su/yFlm2iZdrQstTEpTYwEqTlKIHkVsrlFeFeLZTLBeGW8vlyedmDSoNHOAFIseVWGTm9HDKjWAbO/5E0zrXQzbDhSFvp4CsCnpsmGHxSMf3lixfUaLRVq9HA8OyXLxfQlcK4n6VSzEFIuvDlC3TEcBSMwX1DrKQWwbSTUpkx@p5sy45jRcDcj1@EceOefRGOYnwmnUZgTM9ya2v5lWo1vwLufCEaLQeX@GaYSDdWlKL3S6kgrwaYaeGQiJIKq1EKvQ9jPAutsedV4HAbP@zuPkTUZiu5aKQ5UqJegFQs8hC2ko8UYkXxV1mMslR1mYm/8/NsbGV5dflFvT4evVBMlO/kinRfuZNLOHVwX26Ja1lxm6z87Fm2CGQppMsXgUZjs3ZSa@D7LXBZGsQww0ASOAFccjSt8DnN8@SK9XOsSP0iHC6VX/B2LeRYKFwWcIkwiC5WKFJ9Q2BMqh3cHz8ErIg3ECpJy5nsYio3/C6/lQYjaBk/5@fnhUwhtgxybblYrNfrFLpGKc77w06druaqJM6lfK6eQNXlcthZDplMWs2GlgMmbS5aTbM2rs9aOGe2CIHQpKyJS@m2omnuLbg3hqW1b9S2shgIHe7VNrZO4pk1QJnZrm3EM8en6yEJvbmxn6Kz6D/aqm0enEKCw72t2vHWy913W6eHEI53ZsKnfygrA6Wh3AwGN@hvKPTZUG358lI2zYYJn2Hnx1/9/Mdf/Q8//tkf/vhnP//xz/7k17/8k5/D9y/g@4f8@Yf/ppjD31//8p/9bz/@6z@DwP8A338P33/361/@i5/xL/n/Cr7/ly/sr8TXB8e/AcD1B7/@5R/9@a9/@U/@JXz/lfj@y@nvj3/8f/L//yT@0PlnP/7xX@GP8Pz8D3/8/T/68fd/78ff/8WPv/8PoYn@7i9/hf9/9Jd/9@9/hf//@//yd3/5P/3dH/yv5PhT7vh//tW/4b9/@3s//9vf/@d/@3u/fOD354/@/vIJ4b/8ewh5ejmfgucp9frWkF/@pPL8NtQY5wI8AFz3j3/8F/8I@PaPue9/BB/8e1G/8DxeTIzsuURsHPgLxr6kQG9Kv/jigQLK/xlDIZh9mcRGoWk39Ne//Od/jsETsP/IjyEtzcIuIbCX2y8A9l97BfPD/uLHX/3sxz//hz/@6k9//NUfoCRLrBTjtXhC@sqUEADmngCHgPmnwAGgtIar44tsMZABx@IaTmEEpNinT0DSRXBVGFsO5LLgC9XrVfxcnKeqF6mLKv/UwZ9MVTEkmbpIYXwyBZo7@w5MHfy@eLHMvksk@HMcFpCqhBmKGAN5LoFdtMwnJGI4DwHfYWClCD6coojBMBTjUTGIWo@xSqUSCwwrEEeg4MU0Q1YtoPGFtkcF8GIinibeKIBmy4brhAVSVmJHrLFcGfKEMQyoEgaGBcKgo6CUCcYKlU3IsDLcZIgLkccCn@D5qVItVIZVRPcDFQFwxNYhS4CqYOmG1R/AXyGcAB8Ybv4ARSlUYrFqAUIqVFXKLd6gPKUcVY7qHmNUbwwHQxgez18w9l1QKgS5DQgNwwQ0/sbG0M9pKuQ5xF/ElkV16N910ncZ00OrD4k@PIzHP8dgSi8AAG8igfuy4AvNCAAvIHrIUcUoW3jEOAagXExMJXkBpATEAjFq3xh5IH8ow9M@a1WfB9FhdZaWlsC1Vg1mgwdgTjDrqmQ7soXLFqQnlVgwXwxiMG5zUZYOyeBY3lyGXwn@txZpqyonx3JgKYw6QZi5eSRiWWPFCFHp3apRXZap5DGCC4TG4VzHpbUnUE5XWDQQofvho2S1KqYJzzd2d90Ygh4aDwbjUp7PLkfRqIXID0apVPlBWlkNwJP8A7yaXlySDs2ArytLYl9FglbvEmvUb8EJeks@UK2K9TMmBarHWyeQ4OSASZl0koHyereymlnJreQy2Xw@t5qRVvLFlXyukAV5l0/nMhmpuLJSLBRX76lIL0BuxEvLzdxa9R/MfP67fzDvMz8UP4HqezZMssR9oDpMJFIZKnFFyq2WRxUoBwUFqqSRcTV9dJfAbZOBC9qmdYc7gqBYgbsEsukCfFhgIcAWIAg@gBZXDphYzt49KIt1PXzpB1/bC0o5YIRo4AIYgWMLmBOfALbaMxA1zyTuzOXHzjQ6T/AI2j5kAG2gsz3cQOkY7MTgG/XWlVZgTRyeqgYCtApyDhStB/BK/fN6YC3lxc7HtNHjL8LbsAxQcn86zLqsX/GoTZUfm/GidmS818ruq07vAYhTs48HXBTr7w3DVr8JBcTZTg6wDj@WZhjzAFbZ6eEDtXzjHWnF5UQ60wrgR7svd058z5Ot2sZOIM/WD/Y3px45AZRje1vbJ553lce6SXMeig9be3vTXvFAQ2WR5VbjcRCO8IPPOH3omVz63gWRko/c5g4jU2qNLaElmoPuju9VvahU5WFHHwBzg5nVUCrr51I5VK8WQMKsrOZW8@niKnTV/UGfDZAQ7HRQYN2BM9o9CLzBbWRFiR@HUO3ADhg0fbwXH@9UcAKW0gbj5kankx5NfLvVwGQPBsIDg9Bpqd0eZH9juACBpiwz@H7rB9Ir/o/zeIDD86CwmRhtDjgunKkdlg4kaeIrUyzkCsVsphAvFAsrObD7cnEpE5dWC6vFdFxKSwUpX8gVpXhhpZhdAVEIsbniaiAEIkPtpFIg6aVgkJ6q3sK7a9fwEmAj2asGQnzaAIZXfG1jSPYCoDmC2cJFGtIFA7hFlqmVxSC@GDWNrx0FhDJrsdD29kZ6ezsYXEcPzvNtpIPBNnpyhXR6dT0YVChmA6R1Jhg0eBqIAjCHe9Lp9Y1gcMAR4PHbYLCHnq08KqnBoIqejdr2NuZziZ4MpgewKx7DPZrrWQUwHT3ZLGm5weBnDx3A1XhGK1TSLfRgnhizzWM2IC4YfOmWJ50GDEccjmPYcetaqwWDu9xTq2HMK6p4jhf1NXpq9AkGLfAADwaDXXB0LbDEg8EmOJETg8EWuFojGcLwnmA8qak7cjA44gRCEgWDQ4KWW1dB0KFEOGazs7Mj95y20uWfkcWfLSgaxKjDwdZ28@XLZrfbtEa1rZdHGPPq1Y58ORpYzW5TJGs24GNAGoi56o@mP1DG3UZD1ubGvIYYfSqmMWooWLaG/BnKJD5dzKTfeAUxryBm3sIJxwafPoA28bPeh@e63KQY90Mx9Bw2m8Ey8qgzMhWcXsEuQ1uNyv6QvtyyjDK6QOlmi@FIOD46l@rx2zLFsD5jkehdunyPIJ0IvfMEhSJoOHej82ElXQdVWyrjzE9ksf88CJIuWFqUn0eG6M4HS6BsrwSjJXxfjNEJs3BCej4oBPOrwdIyPIPPg1lwDiPpcJox@Imer9afB1cRSfD580QQygJeAJEhYXC1iAiLqzDwl@@BHg6MRM2BozQakciNIl9Fo7xO/B1T7OzsLHrHt1epVEen3IkM48MKLw1To@VbKPw0pjYeTh20HMPi@LpAgdvn6RJVErIvUPYslYquoURCGQLPTzR1nWSlBH@9ilTIR5O4G7thdBr0ogP2yZ3fPjubcc36USc8w1MVdKLS3X5D6rBdCpyg4kivb2R45r2JbzyiQ6xgkfDLN@j9RAqokcVAoCo0qU3ZkZPbAx0rl8R3MDllEXOiDJ3kjoKbZFpu2AY/u5jcGuJrClVDdyOOR6AP9JO7B8lT3ZY7SvkucZa4p4O0eAoSj@uqbSZXquCS2xHKiMnRGypzo1qtNCp9pW86IzA8SPetemlx5FtnHBLPU7hbyhuVdahKuqzj5RQKepeGoSGomJUBFeFQsfB8w@7BUvq5YlmGFVyj9xS2ep8uttC/AeS5u09UzQFgzpbbQAmw/9bvBqUS5HFf7lbOMdMv@LOWCFaD9UTi/Esd9NtKujwKyRV70KTLD1i6CQp4vjyEMGl1paxBRfkBkiXaRiaXe6xZaX4/LF9VYLBa6rAMy6@UG88bFco7Xab0lfNMuhjPSDBSwQgGAfBdBX8GvlJ9cTGiRRxjSwdypEslpAqQk7zwlKOxzLIWaRtMXksQdaGflAk7RGlMUqTYVaxPQD1mqvFeBJAcKbLGU0cTLLsSLU8QPRItRxZZtGIrn8udCot8H@X6@xcNZ20XG5U01@SX7EH/PL2Yl@J3iUbiXpNtZ0lazZTOB0vnCSx4@kt3LfgR6AcEvA@A0u@fVIbBuQxhbqfhw/l4QB6HmWVQsTQFyC0VM2UBEjBF140EWQTfGMY3S0XC4dVMOBwNlwFqEYJJAkTvqMOGQYyEn4HwAIUApEcxA/GW4gxA9QSxNlMCbq3kpUDoPtBWbZOtFAOhu8D93f1a1dXsXrPRSI4lXO8zxroxsFtTtAiWbITYIrkSyeoLVqvUuke1sgCtbZB1mQqwC34EL5Fa/Nalttha9Xv@vMBFVsgmwIlDa9GptVg1dREIBoOhoLtGEinkotyq/SFEd3ayjbsOCgHo0qU3SCu5dExX6Z/Xoz/sq9pdIZuoksUDXHF/H4pB3XCXRTVFlGod0OaGQEg3hBOnzR2QICAec7kgGr8KM4@L369@X/j@zenB6cE2e5EuFUoFToYLbo/GpbAUBmP3Behl6tFWIGR@MXLSD/qrcqhkhrMr4eyEQn1REafPI8gEkXNcVIJv/RzM2noUXJWK9FxaLam2WPOJlOyBqVjR51I@U8qkpWjIvsejsZnVED2l/GqoHuIoV1aj4KbViowUqqZEsLSKqRLcB9ybC9nFL6FMuhAIFd58@sKY@45jNUOuVEoUdul@7R7@q/fnYM7fk1V/T//4k4Kfew5A/5jA9dBj/JmAG8OM4@s/JNb4/xr9bBzwkgfz0BChT9Ddbfv7xveNUCBUDINBEmaZnCjjUJjKqF0v6/Sn2Mv49/04YNm27WXPB95lqDPLVSUG@ngqdRF9mwFNvFjMF/KhwG9mP6llsOuXF2oszK/F4uMYXorpHb8KT7x1DKdilhcSm8cHG6@3TnAgU3R8ayzbONhPYhS@2HR8fq6lKbKljcSbTUcIhePfycYhM8B82jykNGd0cpJCacZF5LK02y6J1//Er5mUzOJKXi6VXklJOSYVSunVUibPZJBDNt6UIFxLmJRRtTYMc8Ttp8hGlBIv1BAG4/ZUMGJtpcReHu5RCrpEYXlhc@vNATvY3/uQdEN5@MnO7jE7Ptg@OasdbUE93mwds2DtmO0eB9nZ7snOwekJq@1/YBB9VNs/2d06RgSpAMow1Oc4wTxjhq3ZIzuFyp5NFs1EsG20rhRnMly2TDmFt7xOBuv4zhcF35QwGT7QVTCX/MbScW2Ba04M0cvtthXAI5tqiy2gpbSwDAMznhjtpe1Vlhu8v01buUXWWtkPr7JWel/Prq0yLS3@mLbSzx6xxcXFCz3oDQD@ani2mj8IN/tD2LhMux@3FiL5FbYMFlpmJTqO2T84XEi7voWzo5MFyYs72lzIeJ7d7YWs59kC34rn2z7bXMh5vvXa64X8ONn@xsKq59vc2lgoeD5g0oXiGOf@5oKUDrjEugblaYHeaxfZ3t3bYssAFC1PxOI8GDqmgoEQEVCH@P0ZZJwuL9/0jDip@s3RFHRb@Rq0Cz4BtYCq0znStR5ny4YJP6DMATAkC3i6t2x1W3GBFW9EgpElcBdYwAotYIUAfgFPbiMcW6ywTJRB9EKHbyqI8Bvy4ix4atP5zO9stoZKdBWYIU5XLNE5XUihiBdcBhbuBcpIh@YKO7T5mEDBoGFBKxiN4uG@/dO9PZ6ZSYpiJEiQjGuNc3AaJmCDKsIvVh1CeePwZqG2QFotCK0CX8IZuJ9ozcB0ayIpoJ4LCy1AMEnda1mLM9Sq4rhijXjRww8NADBEgzsNLn6qMRJpYV27itOiAkWRmFsH27yGuOZdYZOtHGWYKVGKovlxhC9fmOu7cCa91qRXD3PcAjkvFsfHS1pB2CiGLbjHSQmCjs5TygXkmFgMUkN1KM5XrwUgOnz5SXu3lFXIKB1mz55ROdbAVwxTFpguRjmyBIIgAkEwIh8i84q2SMWNLqSWcTcKf4M9EhHHEX7panPk3RICknW6oFOt6vVCrzkXdLAdy1MCWUR12tjW4M5mGuBH8QicHGdN6CZx5kZKeYxEKyvOlDjrQPCUTG2oOnCuYo1lossK0Bmp9fc3eQvxK3EonAdQjUHulajBQFg8w@5LjL6w0LTAgi67UCAPCQr4FpkmgoTgcI@nO9qkZMu8vyBbYuqnpNzdLrl8xFMDOwhOI7LiLQacV0R1KbA6BprBL5Bh/60Aes6SHFksJiA8LhNgW5NwiQSHu3f58iuV2JquxeI31wLF8oO12HpiNX67WsCwNmYRqAWI@AjgjQE0/Uy2ZmYeChgLCQXV5qehgAF0zEvQxycQPCE9DLnj9IlvTw@DdGm6K0O/hRbkUoEnmfS2Jr3tSS92XwiRGdgEmRX2hTXRJeXBhafZWQEcbS4rJxN2Jr00CVNhipum40lgngPwHIpKDoYMOCuMUYIkbXxBhNzH1xRVWG27sbu/dTIZi/iSdkMUvOcYukZ5RCfBRIEw3o6gJ@qVKNJBInB9M3LI84gTPRvHJ0dbtTdxKF@UrY17wLQOAD@iJ0zU4N7NAUJ1pQXjcTvOIsc1thxlz7BkcSYmC9Dz5Cw0w1YA1YM5tgdmhrJKcxDPP9mTQtgjA3OyCkZYJMq@XFzAkJpeZVLf/JLtZ/XVbJuNsquo7HI8ng4ipLwrYPZ51@TKBkK2@W2ApbmZXabTbMXKMkfpgcY9TFuz@Kle9zi20bDonrk1DTLK7DLDI84oW8QNJTAuTqo2j2uRNDYiH2AodmMIw@GcJuBipJ8je1Ksq2DxsrSVby3L1zTaybIkeFnWKNPZMvxGTHaCuRSYOldNF70YpmPKePRYRB7QFOkhBlmBAJ9n8d33FTHw1TBOtET3tKBMaTTwGtBGI2IrWgffQj@wWjDko7psCzD8YGySR1JHQsdkpCAP6k@TEW0VjwrjJYsw6kwhxJs4IBhvF4xQjoGAVzLbUUwqla8YOE@G70z2ZwgG9oQfmhWP8PlKHC0JrXhbxv7gIjufuKKJ4xjYvficYBDPs6Eem86J89hmThzexDcviXu0fE7c5aA/rwQgGB6IEYdD58ToxsG8BPyGo3FE/dxHwHM/gev1SHR@00O/mmxx3xVVRP8Ta6CI@5Z2D3wsCMql4EBfW4c2FWDalooX7k8j8o6nQ8rIMOo7Ke@xVXTMSbLdUtVp9C4mgYiOetKd8mxYavUA63dSphCN@xD6MLb5paMP4WQ@pFDCOUhC7Jh4350BtT3UyILTeMfpk3jRg94G826cwDAfgcfYMSw2vgu8gHd0eTEeM8/pcmN0pVnGoXCcdMfmlyZuM3sI2q2EFPUT9LfNPvGt2Sd8@WOf/ElZV9j5ZDnqMZ@/BAHjOrod/Cdl5JZ6MrfoN9XYzzWKcvUA@@KtM75s@G0Tk9l6aIQE8njKrQqhx4AnCgnE5Uf0DfKFmk@chZ@Xejz@LFdYQvLScIk37g00ue4rfADvyWg08ILZRoNuFmw0cGap0QjyHGjgxQHPP@iKzsbjkqClNgyKjQQTcjAeTCRqxxu7uwlVD8b5HeaVoO0YltLAC8KCcVz2rQRJYDUQpqdoZiUott/JNqPUwYfzqPnygAp@PRMC4rns6pTJ@ObYr2fX8lfJeEKVjKnMxrdZPiG3I8oND@4/lpPFr4VzM9qgm8vwKjhLUVHQ8NvZxQvH8YqPiZslcEpfFIHna9NMn433efAi0aOBYaKt8WIMeq17hdFsX9C96SY4czGN6O041YMIxpzKuS94SO9wYnTrWVsRehZNDyWD4xsvRcGSoqY@fncVNH5RyHhAm7z9RpQ37s5N2jiNOVXUsWAxTKz8eRAvx4EGODRM@PUuyAG3d0UOuPGSHAxyRR248YYcTNERDnFZDrjouhx4AnsHx7dz9uWh2h/gxI3/CgahyY2LhUM@1oRGfYqclH6cogiR1PCa44jAG40FS0Gouk1X80xfz4Pw827oidYDs0KW7pPGYvpUh3lI5975E43/DhrJp4ihaLZFaSBtPMiCXAmhtFKpDsanj3dcEYPq81SYwWc9ERHUJO6lH49Xvht@KhPmBVIEjAdemHECPsvkf1ciKffRkqeCjFvMD8UVtznlxg20Dxbcj8FV1KKBRyyp/9/YSf4m@a/UVPr/3iiaMX3@nk2ZR0yYb7ZWfodmwX9T6P@bQv8TFPrfmTb/gEo@jXK2x0@p619Vw79d/SKZN4Jhw@pe49Rb5qfoYb8jRWD1m/QAt9Tn0mO6wNfHZxdNxj@s/8RROvCb1Ek7f7Zt1Gq1k75kHb2sdWu92hFeprSe3oudXa6sb96sv1xv1zY3u6@6G/vK20JtZc98/b7w4WXn9rMC2vvOwauPt5rZ6gXeH5k3Z8rhTVYp2LXB4PPuzsjZWT/tbxznPqzepLe0XGdd@byp2ZtvTt6/PnmZO47dfH51@Oq2n@7bh520XOxnd97k322MzvRA7lo9bW/vqQf94/bWaaa/t6l@2I5tpPeOi2@l9N7Wzcfsxk0sl07tmq8PXh6dXja3PmpHu3sf2hufDTn/@erG3E21i52Ny6N3gYPsW2nn88FBdytTfLmTutnsmO10Zkezcpfvjw7XTz/s9F7LW/3t3Gnx/eXoMN97@/ba2Y91V87ygzf2SkyvvX2bea2/vL7eOgo0ZePEyipnxlvJvLk5NIr9VeX1/k63/9aS9NRB7l3suH9ys7m1rn1eHWZPP5y9vVk5/jB48/bVx4O0enzc3JLzZrOdOb48WQm0@tnd2PXp1mlBftk@e9u/3t3JfdhMvekp@7X2oXb1srvz0Tg@3NutZe2BLu1tXGsfXvYu31xtbuxqxuGVptdWUjntpP3h4CBw@kptbio77@1Xtcveh1Ru/WrlQ6xtvjy5vO1dvVo/Pj0oZIaHo7SxYR81dzrDzaN8ppBqaZ@PbjvGG@n0bSx/ffkqo36o3TqB7O0oV9zTPih9/VWs1f04/KylYqeStPFx9/bDh@Oda6tZ008/v9s@urTetPUD@yB99Or1m6Z2VXAuzY/68bHUSr9Urt7E0nJgeLpjQxspJ3Ju9aS/99Ycbhqfj3Y/2vnb2PXZVVbZvDp6V/t8lG7e6OZ73dpT@xvp9oFce2c4W4Phy1bx@vRqR9v7fGB/CLzZknK5baNjr3ferRTfp17GOlcv369Lx8P0vn7UWclb@@/enqnqVu/96e1RK7f9ziz0Hb379va0vxXb2hv2bpVCuqkdf7jSA6e546PDzI3@Wu072ztHb/LOQXrv3WF7ZyTV3irSjb66McptDq189mzzvfXhakc3Ux/Uz4PDtHIda38wnZW3arPTeqe2@q8Dx696p/uH7252c3nrZV9X1w8L6f29nY39bnvl9Wj3zWBrr3nZfrn7XnlvnuSvMlvrZ/nN98dZ5@TqtVNsXfezh4XYidZ3uqexwKtBb7B6eGZ9fjf8uFLrN5XskfbBGK1K/Y1XZmb4rrZ1cNu9OjSNfWk7M0qd7hlXWvr25OZ2x87XRrHC8NTpG86JNMxJbwPZm1vTeWW@ent8sP7q4OMreUVVz@TL43ftdPa0kFJ7VnY3n38pbW13@p/7RUW63XyTlbP9Xszeu0q1N9qn786utMv@6/5lK1Ao2q313Y8D2dhqZqT0h/XOVk7ZW987kZTT7uvjlc399OH79uHp5@FJe@P94PTdgZreunxV3OuuvD96V3y9@vHEPpHPjPevrf3AsJA1bClfzN1kj4uFg551nD27LDofX1/m17WzpvRqN9NXtlXrfWFUuDJvezfdm2Ml3ey@3PwsH3W2QJKeHqbl3OBqf3gcyL476V@vmuuxD1et1@91SSucqaupk8@Xxate7/XNZmvlrHb7Wc69vFSKx9uppradexk72nh7eNndPLstrLTT63vv5PfDrZ7zIfB2R928LJ5dHQxH0tvt41G/lta13PXxWe76xFg/Pts5LvTeNK1Oc@eyB7KhPzq9vBlc7yirveFN4XXv8p2c3ntf2NDtlcN04JWy228fnbx@X4t1MkrRuT74sG@eFc6GuTcF46xoHBTU17XOy@Hbg85WetVUz06Gp1u91PqG2i@ATDnUTq2Ng7c7H89emelARs@v324YudXPsevhh/xZ6jC2N/jQOsn0zyxr571qbb@/Pnz/@ri2G9ttjl4eXskHH7Zyx/sbG/ar2LaaV0Y72Ru7tpHVOkbA7q8P94eWWcx@vNrrwkhgtIvtlyfZM92u1To3u4XjrVrtpd3cfSUPhy87qzBG4Gfr7J1RCfyGX5QX4Hfk8YfMb@QI9O1u0xiCvOQH@gJ0XCtAx7UC/IAWbZHm249/k1oOnPhPKtCbfvkEz6AJyhprG6g8JNmud5stvswizvoGJFfR1TJMeiJacSCjjQafBr80X4VHBuk9hcrQ1AwV3xOE7yxAm9Qav1IsGTjQWX@E9qaj9Pn5CRVf9SMun6XXHPA3KtHll4GFVou5b3NM0tWq3rsdP4ECYerdBN2l22WJRKujyV0bHFqbXJ8Cx95d75iDpso4@YFZSHsNWUrnxNZUegMbFu4E31C0/5JpBn@JgmtxyKBMjOhGEpykoltJFHzjm61eK9qI3oqhtJMBvuPzSbsg/WG4vXsyjC4AndobCuqGYk1tADV5QnelNbX8Ai@LebGcEkusqAw1ZKupOvg@4QY/C9HgObp73szJvYd0kFcs0HLFCDUbujo3Ls4lDdE3lQopRtvMW3SihCNA1RBVVHe34fKySShp3xXjHh/mZfNh3Gq/@7tCPYG7rSoTeA2g1QBoRQvSM2v239m0ydEDKgf4Yv3W@92Thnh1Ct9iOHHa6YEdlz4ql12fWeY18JVflHx2WybuMIDi47Qjv3kaqnptcF4O0r5H3B4JrY0W9ni3ZRK4hnYaIDaTdqOcr9T5DsI0bd1zCe6lecY54ZmvVM/GBF0QGyo8HnhiOr5Bk4PM1hcRdyxFIQDazekeDZna7Pc75r0HWqapyfoVusp8qyzYC1bL11j0UghfPXAqy6uL2D9JNgLWG5J622DHBQ1aXrMQgNgQ6zbzqY7dmfbbYxrewl7WOD@GeXhWl6YZrcg4etndcsPrFnVz4vBTWR3gTGIHd9Ya1ohnhNMzkXIZQHCfDskERXd3q/pqXRlTA9HRph5fKYBvy24Q3hqgjMsZZ4@Xlme1SOxAO4DmF5VvBkKoc69YdZ7Vw7IQ6B31V2Yi6Zg47hYicKaWmWOYQISO4DgYxohH@O7UGarwnV4eFzFOp/N0Hf7Zc7@nxDfuYodScNoTRUgUuzFa6FOF8wqNoFWv62BWY9ajhsId3NiEKvEiU8HCx3CmxmIT7eRDfq4i3SQWI2pH5sSCGPJqJEgvaE8wtCcOWoNvxWUdvoOL0zowRaI1yOjLF6/DgNfjxkP3gCWwhPf2cmRwzpm8LwuCll2/2wk9N8WMieJJ1fvZvfR0tBQMcOPGVIeKFgGB2cBXwpgMgsSWJdPkDoLwti9BMDY2lV3Iq8XFCKQ6J7hUoc6esYi0thZZTUQo6LtCNOp1RpE840vuSwxCulplkcxyJOsmXsHEgDI7iWBlPoIMR7CyHJFcBBmBQMoBBq5iEJLvWIFz7STigg@xh7c@CYMvlpmT@3ImJtXX1gq4x9MXOJU4M7/oy9lYBhJz1AuxyRiOlkf4wuuTNQLk2YxvHPGhWIllAQXPOjYZMc51KsLL1J/nSn3u4PQ7U17ccxru4EPJ8f2WinVewPoip/JN6SYDt@lYIhDfMWbSm8bGYZyll5HNQUegLgm59RQ8NBXnb5oTgxbQrzw1KvoORxAEigEigotHjbPLx8a65rcPdgjcoQk@Xuc4k@KsAGYISBSQGAVIDCKEaKB2G62@6cHBUFyI8h3ffACjTPZxxRnPD0A7odrv5kRijJMPV7gBn3jTF40hnL4RSNDY213Hx7utI9wxu7v/EppwAesRZ@Nft5qLHKNXxQ1Z528fUR0VigCyjRs0oq68qSbzx0A3f4HNRS7gp7HzhFQ7hGA8sdAOiS9Up6EaAhsnpctHikN0pJdheQCFaBnsDHajMFlDcoz4S3wL/J1ZdOiNUhOpwOElFAVECiHNTo5q@8fbB0dviHKHjdre4U4NMYOB2ZKtNqO3umAH0XVF44OqR88ADr9dfDE21kluuq8g4a8MR1j@ekBOPABsUEyDQqdLhPXlTD8Dz4PnJSCJ4kGDUtFoK@Yc3Lh31QMTlbHnIOStyEsthkJRpnkjIQ14syOhK0erKOmIloZi62EHGJveciPrXJ6kXHzrYGXSKwKp56Ie1SV@sfg70bIZelEy8pE9MHF1WGkH/eSXWy3FphsNxtQHlIrWoUyEZPERCkLm134sP/jZFG/sFTjoPZE06KY9vXes5k4qi6A9ctr9JB3XpyBxLK6OdOeqlaQWiZz5e5snVEd1UmV8KDOe2yXP7RJy4wKXXU4rZGr9/HJCEZtHHtUlzyXXjV3NjKsn3lZyarkOdHq7h/cM0VwIlzrUYNhMdMeGMZqQdc/cJnvm9uJxT5yv3D2ulAnCTmpkYsAZj5/CYG63gWyRmbkNOrlC1tfAwvbnHl25QQ@NlPygk2tiEDxxSgPUaRfOFZ94hupBzkBMIA3ptMy5yK5Og4qHLyIQsoRbnqhP16BTmGJWQNVBWowPp4m6kipp2MJQ9AWiWBWjsNV2OzlBjgczqz19oAuBMJQfOByfSuDH@HhGBXTSOyYrhBo5ZKyzUgTXVRMJSBDl8xqk04C4xTpQ8VRnfjUKs9UQlXN1MpWfgEFRJ9wSFwUI@gXsHgh1My/PrbevHu5hOEwc9VUsXRYnKNwTvaeHLCtls77jvwdn@yyfH58OxjvK2EomPT5yjLeVsXwx8JPmycbzCZwfseOIBkW2Qp5B0x10QUXToBPzR1vFoR/Lxs3iIX@Myp5ytcwtWFuIYzE02KyPb69vKviWdlyvdZg0lJKBBRCKNAcsXn/pDt4A2B3Ilqw7Cj9jiYJcrOxihpQQdVjFgnrha@tx2xhKfHx5OwwLlsIngCGkbbRokyTioHTQ0oM@7UaKo8JwrVh4DYDqiIP@CyRzBDtw0VDlTOAGusKh6vIGJ6EQCdSjcZKFk5GGZaQen3oRrgypKyd7aSrlyZ5EQ5r7Jl0sAJFXsArRmLsDC4LAM8MM2ePL4nVibpf0gMeif97U4Owgw41T1w4XaPgYM2v5q/U5kzHEXS3/GDQUm5gIFdWpHnXPwJEEcI9Atdx5CA5Ej2GdhifCxa1RpCDYL22Vz4UzkhGkRdAoRUOKhVyHu3TE9XUUveC9S5z4uQK9Lyp2BozEgTnveKSAQJaPcghxNnIaAvsnhxj6cUApeEddTo33HwwRh3feDcU3cYhrhaM7KuwCRMDtWlK7ePn5mbT5tRB9lDLlR9KmS0pRUV9fng/GqyzAsHY@MCgUySO3Ui7Y6eH43JsLSKWnCanHCj@R21MLL7KbAZqgxBOL7hHiXszVzUMKifvGtcIXqcS2GqFm@tqHK0nQiIIRiGep34upCkEDVyrw0jV9KbjO7KZxJQnFiEO/syJHQHmO5Yx7HNgV6N405/hc77yKck52q@pWk1qQ3uetqSYNjZN1Fd3CX9eENFvZVV9l3VPGE5UVidx6zt7voIOjoxk3/P4FHFCC4uRy8Lt2nH3XxsUQEeIfo1xqzJN/k2edfR3y@8q4R3r188pKh2Y9D@@rYu0QRbuf3zEd4k27nRxf6ExDgITghl52N9fzVAsLQp0BpWciXSYqpp09dnZRdDogr2mrPt5Ku5dxMY05hrBU2A8cDw1Bt4o1AeyCfSE5jwWIerD4Uns/rI@LhGSe6KQud2BELCbGs8rEbPD4APWDjOjHImSn74jyo@lJpsyWYoRxfJicj8NNIob7cf8v@wsyerAgSA5aIxJjnbdmxK9EuP9tV0bHupspNDfQu8wM/HwWipjQ33JpVw@ImGN9wbMOuD3g1w2Eou0qgzixBQo82Mb8aHScQe4Pwo9vGPnMF/jwaB6kpBtA/Mnoqgm/QOIlzPjMItNnxMwWk1qHKGryNpksNzUkTYR42Hk1npnniCyVSeAyIHfGpJlaTaBjdMiZZuPK/PIPUmXxOnGyU/23f2DDL2PlcclybGeZeDjY3e1AKNS@qSn85I6016gd7HpXW7Ge45ilVEqxDQyyk4bVTd2oV2qKAwaOxbVVCWWA/RwvqeIxja1TGMrwwiknyY4VvlkB9V5Uyz6ROakMop8wEd6ApQNwpwMar95S8JUmzg3uHxAI7KS/sBAt26CHGzobGUZzXHpZnMzhBYhT2W0ofBcIM2gmoQCpluzYykhJYcJUU4Ofvox3Q6fAJE9hDVMHurIHqY@hSyjJS/laDmz6CkYnp6dypWvoAgmcO6IYB18ATrtHcA7BwX2RrGlA23j7U4WRQJdEGro2YjpeAdCV8U30jN5JDFkh591ANWnHrVjUoS0PCtkRK@linoS9LUY4SofjdzIJcblogL@8toTnO2wD2cVSaG8qJZ/Y0zK1J4N3zMlNFNzOnwxr4eVcX9@n4W3xSKV8aQ39Kfs@5u3xoPu/gOwP7fxIpXB61NTkEQveyHQrN9tYWU3nS2hrqV2d2BB7C16i49PYlaGJr4DFjQE4jrtpNeVa0VgWm/Gdag8A8NgZQJUCIdOSu33ZBYxkSwyz8d3RRfb1xIn@cZRhaJMhHTw3wcYWNZ5MY0waY6MTXGJUQWKKYDEuKFGQWvDzHLc8G4bJSuBoK81BlwYDPJflpsDTUXK8iQnkaDXSjD6HZwmeUHQs0jL0Y@z8Fe/@KtxPZKjsHLp5nbkLFMFygGoBXb/CS1920@PIgWC@FR0YsPmqBowIy6whjFE@SwDQOIZFOJzN5z1p8dwFaRu7BzhrQxnyzcVuDFbRFJc9PrinZJn59pSASMD7ppAx6QqsVMqdGQnX8GW@rmc9zGNp1ijC3eMpIj7qLXvkcPcvdPjukzW6E4zRJZ5EzmjZ3VUvldm9C4h7QFDDwZ0libC7cwA1TAvXZsY7UoD0QdcKewytrwDZr0BSwyGb4bjkqwbf4F3ns11CBZmOluruGhaEV9Jllxr83d9e@48Xs57x1lygii/Sm8TvmFCngy2@EEOrJGKBaaKsOHgJHiHu4LjEEB/h/EABk9wgZhNp0jTuTajygvI5VxAWqHMmaEiJsyHr4uw7N5/ibCS8eAV9gN8ynY6PKlLZu5Za0Qf9OzRG4jzJwIwj8D1TQNqXA/grLDqLZ@71bhglSKyjIA@QoMCgczccpzbu0nEm3Zcp5xa94IuLeNAjZnl/7l6sCx3xlc7BFKH/Oh8mSt@1g3GeHy4ZkENyHZl6fJwbJ6JX6uHIuIoM4yMQHQzPI1WF1YFuMTlP3pEviu4oEes0QsDgPGxDxnXHBtIu4t5AxhrDChhIjVEF5/D4/V@o8PJuQRfIIHyJAWAigYBgoTJX2aV4IjOIvmEshvFg1E3GD8wSWtlu@pl4bD3Cz9P78d@PL8kjOjSG8cYo6u5LgRSN0TKRwNuecj9TXSreb1HfmfJO1XeGHl59H6CHV99Zev6k@nozxu@pIjDE0ANtHDTZn4NFDdBeIJ@neM4wMD0eoTY/TKcemPj@oKnU9GqI2dSGaRo2XmI@vwQ8zzmFoHhfOOT5nOdRAjcYyCk@fSQV0tD18Lp/O8C7uGWgvhghN76okY9foE9qfG5bjNEUgJiLNKPveRNTfsggKoYSf5ArEr36YVZcpnJ1AtS2K9pfXGG@rMpewami3AZjlNirfZRxrw@Hr@q0fRFK4yZBQkXZvCQD1Dsw3XQSDJufRFBdyMfJVEh1NjeV24iYWuyudDUhEjvBXW4ljbXuoG@tqUHSGdjVp094dqw33zuMuQzOG4NmesMxd5QGU2y3Q7NtG3wjNjsUs1N47AlUeKdnGYNuj@FFUagDIizfUt4xULtH7RK0enw75wDvqim52@Ii4@p788cpdmoyMPLp/Dz23DeHbAMV/@YI55L5XEDEN0yIHVYLC67utDCe0l4gSe8B1/lEH59xGGdPbeYrwCbyAxThDc7EQfZHxE5zMnYHsYTkaSBB2XHwznzUrFVeBaz@OJmJyzDjhKgBuHd8kbKy4IHOLyxnY19pqXT@4u4Bq8wrbXpuIekY6nQhmwpO9aUfKRyfRZyeu4HiYO5Ymk3l76H9vFz56jXY/V9hTcjU5co4wSlg5OLmaFB28GheHy8gx5s1OKeCBQ4o9w0LbcNRfC7mG5yPo94l34DtRaYywsWSojg9sGevcaPR3NS04taToano6AAighKQasXXznC9DN/VhqnfkDnqJeYGsE2qHN47y4thtHCV2U08SwnLaClK20aVVUZeoXJG8HiD6K7uKmFblbtoIYKl7opetzg0H03WYk9t8VMZG4dYFEv5PFAtbmxjaZLQlrTvB1hho6e0rggW31o0xp5Q9QSQTXcSRofZnweyhVMOhsViYTsgZDwfaY7ETpxpPUoIqPIEMHFeZVYJ8QGj@olXQU6xlTtfh1M1rsyjzTr4po2wLd5zIeaMkLb@uR@cNUkykFfehAwMz5o4oavahMdnfsdZZ6ChLDbMJMahJJysrN@HimVzscIvMZyops8zAcQF62SsD6PYhmJ5GCI0jIuRmEuar4MXZ6AxqweAExzas7F89PWIBqScoNvE8g4dChrPX0A0zZ9HkN9sF6aDey0sRZgQmCYdjVMms2hpKJ7Fqht6wo@Zg80iBjgEi/6/7T3bchvJdc/CV7SG2sWAuFOURBEcLiWR2mUiiQpFee2CuFhcBuRIAAbGDERgKW7FuaeSSpXjjR07tlO52Eklr0nKjquSh7yv/8Ff4D9wzqW7p2cwQ1La9bqSWrm8xHSfPn073X1O97lcdv6cL2j@BDJAI9x7YINB83e8Yey28bKSmi6lT1jp1EskZNkV2AeG00HYHrn@NBjMf92EkLtCITgl7wxJc/r8mvyMs@MohrF0VsVgAGK3ukfqbqibgII6bN4rD9YxxzqQWw1O3NCX56wYSDOYoKSC7@AzkX2AeQ9kHh6OSicgkYMuE/CmB9UEQrLxKrHaAGydZC42CitUTinYtbvhlDbRYx@VK1CndIr3QajjMUETMZoS3LCxL4jcH7sTrgyobe5PhTqfgV4jV5@wQUa@Nj2oVB59hB/3ZuwW0j0fJIAHcRuoUOXwyDXKwPYLDQdwujuCdqvjrePKOwo83Ph1CwNsYg1ULfxF3B7bwEUVvnFt/AqHd75YJeJOlKuhWwFYbMYtGevZ21elfF9Qgn5C/4lYZnXXpWCZoKRuP74kkFbF4rWcEmC9Bila2J6DmhobaGEB6xJAm97hVQffWlhrg@7OcBZPgEDc9qR7DF2C@fKQYMIJjVPP69GwgQyH197alXkgAD3GKCowAz2aDjvokqZP46XNNOndAy/JAcSOUBeo5sj00qMdzisCPT9DVU@6P@4V9NriqkguQeEHAPU9Ep6gsk10fykHBr8jzSY9On1bfuJVyAoOC343ZSK6KZH@6BeyVg6V53ot8q00khjr52AsRJdnCZMwvPAKDRWnE3/ygl@O8NqNdv6w7dG9N74FssIyFlI3evjIH0R5/JKhLueisCa0nvFgOW6HF1/yKmoKYVMcsEEPG05FA8xveI1IaVlrI9eYtmAL6/INVFVmoWYUl@WXS97YNfGoN1e@Q2TboJppuiXH2jGXAs@1vMpku7bJoC@5qxhtSEhJEQitWo7X7/JKUtVRJjQExY1nGYcaX3QUWEOaO5XNlDMU/7mdavgkrbijzZpajUwfjsPUEdWhlYS7hqrusjJvYH2y2PBTMFxHB3B4s3GjHYOvUxtiJvW7yNJqxhpeVxLyt@AeN5ElvXJl/jqjQ2Oh1cSjO3mLqFkuA5I7tDLgCtNGQspTG2Ofl36KqYpU8uRwB3C8CwymIM034NO8DA/Cgn6ulws0CCtBSLRjnPRl3n2AvtPWXXsQ@NKVGR2sXCig98LXe4lRK5Crl@uuM@1jU/ClH8pEBiqL1ilX@3rLIdVcfvDnkSJw0jucIg5e/wVDW1A51GerFYAikxX5wi8LNtWdOKKXatR9eUfGPRDLLVmt7INyYYSdoAdvw50NSVXvTtwj@LPvYYt6QR75Jf3yXclt82Xi473dRwc7@639na/s7D/ZoZKkyK8NiqfjKt2UBSfo3Hsk8eaDmEOc3PsTD85xPHEozhJK4E@6fhiK@yDuuiCOv2hDyfbUzWW@ua88yM57GriTdS5/wMw8Gd@TpnHgoYnQFFWVoH8nLIDz87AdFJj44Qwkh1So9TpATwYcFyqHeyZs5pyD@yeupI5PUZ8JQlo24JHi98MT5AClNBF/Y4aTZtCD1exWpI6tgsYrh8hfgnaIgAwA5KPW7bxCgcfNtQoD7wLPiWwktpWDCoPsfa8mHnO121St2OZ@IQ/ZHvijo5z0nmC0gDg3OLRKGNZ8XQ0xGQVBFai3gJ4CcaS5R9yhKsoH1XqlVv38XBpEj9i/IW8Fb2CS/4Z23ot2@qnxk9LM9lUMAIPHOUvY0MXCJqVa0KVHa4ob1CUqWpEVvZk5ebY1uUR//TdsQZ5hQC5bt/rFGI1/vvbclzaz/sw@Fr54M5xUAo5Z5SjyTVUxPfv8DHb@r1iNvJ65yEVWFF@aTqSbTsiAaq9jPJFfzpP2MXIeu3t8YY9XTfr6J1Da3TKcUYInU7tWTNFWR7CJK81H8WikJvLllOhjGvQxtfJfmzp8dl9TbAGi7qarHb9Grw3jiFhHa6@lCa8D9Vyg4m5q65/F2q/qNdX2UaV9MkfeM7pIwzUnmxtXkabd5tUrEVMDZ0sX1vEl8pca5tq8RTmVNy7jlDK6PDvUnRmXTKi/86VgSmkd5C2UMbI4vFY8xJykVtMmUcLVGjGFeClHFRSus8XxS6itRyMYXZaSEzHzEl@21V7GscFAVHQ2oO1BITlHMZTRZWwWyvjUqLnIqkwutAWbEP0C///F2kqTIBt4fGlk9Rs0svrSauRLq5EvrUbOsxpZulqdBpNqxxtVgTUbiPIJcP@5JVhQ23vi/ffuHIiD93bE/af3flt8be@peP/OI0jZE4@f3n2we0/A/3cePdkRVED/@4o7QZV7AVO/7XZdup1fqdVWBWFeCFC@Kp60h@I9v@u@BOLZCNrDrWP@qIzccJNL7bx0J3Ofn4PGqMwSSqsJuivityZ144QW1x2g5CG@IypfnthG8uYZ8M0S2V5QOHRtwM1ve8SDkB4XPStpow2A9yEV0LT5SZZ0p/FpnZiWXkXIgdP/XnsEgSl8@ETcebSNkT63dw929x49Eff39uHz8dfQzY7Y3kW3MXefYhYBPtzb3r2/e@8OJXADahWBd2tksH5eEyoITqPSfdGfYniwAUqF8ivm1Xsplxv5yioiEPnpKHLf0wOSwnd3dnbaIBft9rU7@@9@Bbka9@vCsjDIpeFQXVogXKuh0QjUJqNoN9iZOrKW5TpvSMO5uIbZjRzdAdHvklDIC/RO7LnCuofXiPggTXGzmWFTqKGiq4AbUSlHsI6gCAz5fGmDUG5CbXR7oGrDi9W@@sCiW9IxK8qRS8pLa0BIMTjj7qjLYXRVAtA9a3VTteGEAfBCSCYwAN7BYELYfuHu4iWJuCEhpiEK/pBwkxOeD8f3T5BrRANXmXCXA4GsyTbxvNGUYoCjtjfieYyZNfHuQDFSqEhA8OgkZzBQV66kEgf8v3xjw1dZgLRgF@zDylZCRfTsBtQAe/txux8GwnYKeBsMIog78lhT62jQBnGP7oUnaLD0EtUIqNo1B/9tKkf1iuGkQJxKhOnMRbwduty2PPjdy5aDkncXakS9Peo0KkzJ@E8XNuDuQgPeBA0gKpv7BboVGofE2BIavy9J2Q58oEgQ@cTH8ahGfm/adWMFpKxjP/c@@qggB7kUFTFUfKh1WsMOQz3gQ8gJ@qAiNxcgxJCm5DG@RvEc2vEeRG/DQ1SGmGADP1SDK2szhQdVo9TEkZUiP59Ra6dNxnAX1koUz7rBevsaa59R9PwdsFkePZN0UEzW0lyA/pxRiQE9O03QzUtfoGLRPKSWcHCHXLR3fCyCavODNWdz@@6z8scflg6r1SPeFto9frxgpUR@ZiGRHJaH1p0kbUC10iTSXDDtYGmlz8i7Ja5yhQwYl2MPmO@tVkPn8bXqYvqI4mXF0ynx1SuHS5XJ3oRICCPJRLtbSTRVlSUqcygKEkG0d0Jj0bOuSikRTr1fb2Fce5yFBozICPcRUq8xw6qRfo3h7Rof9GBnyUk@jadb4y@oWOSSouifbc5H9QP7rlPcLFQVFC0mPZy22qJLCnO9IHt1htNL59UCuu3z0cH@fXl0a@e2jo@H18K2fS6212pbuZiNi48lA9fl0X58Dlo@3N4ILfS9lI2YD8lFbJrSNXGWri0pmr@gxg8X5o7WHqDBsxcjqmqkRm3T0QA9xNl8KQ5NowIFE03EED052N7Z3xfWDt6yrUNZ2Pfaoy7Zl@I2iLivKk9HbIdMm11FM006TJBmnlTKGZuXxqs9bzGnDl7GViF5kJIcD71Z6Ki9IJnMpHUEnyzEQqDhNW@IauTirTtVe1DQlIjPmqgJJaJJMzqYS@3mEh8@7GSfNplo3ErMGwcvvLFmZtyZdNZFV9WTuYlIMcJ4HLSP8OU7ff7eZ/54XdXDDJb79Sl1GJXwu@gvXzyBisf4UlyJz@A506KmlHRWiEqX1NiRWV6cw/7sBKVjsZ9JXtjY1iVzLJvG/PE1I5Id8adb@M4/l5ndobzvVFs8pWyYE1qIDj07fgQBkwlisNgyqQKKH57JI4xGQ5@TjmbIzbV2jVrTVK2kaGYSdyMb6C3g4G/cTG4Pyapgtz23qvLnUxWfErGajLhbizWoTMB888aN6xfhTvZCFS9/Vtx8hiT3z3A4ftk2UAbzgFSFgHJ3H5VUfkQA5wydA1Jgz1YLJlEQWJ2UMyXWdzqMzPZBW04maIsHjdl7elDC@6JkrQUxS7QtHTufSCZ2Alnog7GEdUd51SyM/tn51d2loG4X1Hf19evjxYZAeB9@9isOk7nvj3GrBEZ80mKvqCCSrweoFRdiCQ4@qD39GjEwt1QcyybHm9viF260keYat0L/Ber1q8iZMraZhc9QlWF7fPoKL7he0ZUp56FNgCzrlcTWc9ZR4ciaWz2flAj6OpTlFrcyngbb/MuWGXxzHdUHKY8BjAdMRw9g/u28ALlnHW8VVKjJfJHTgD/RSWVOAloNUfbQ6cucjnYJ3ngw1@lVTu@5GHhOp25ILCdtHfEyvykhkxEy85YEprtarz9v0bDr7Hc4G9gYnfSWbAzIlgNfp17lVNSpUklNWXYaJR1yEkhSOmlJQuHB5IUmLQWu@6JFkyyjzQHCfEmMvMFhRepPvWNL2bEgTThCnkgo7456OZoUinmqUakjYQtdy0oSam55hxVSoJQbEMpk0cTyQtryogImMKQboS@ZqLgYNQD/Kxshm2oSL9bc3HqOFD5xg@7UFTszlPFVbERFleQYZEnsPNoWe/fF/t7jnThqbHELeRQqpRT2KBSzbBh1Ry3ZEky4Pw2PW5yoPpO5Jy7nKhT8rYFG/sQA4s9krqqAUBzishSnr3qvRBMO77GeFLtXOJSTrnqs@1Dp@tNRePpq9oqmdwacXgVI4B1xVsFLgncWhkWuRMlhK3KgtzgMC4l8ZUu5VYhqoRSqZSZ9c/jS4jqx5gtnEltO758wdbAyaZOOAnLCNok7gY8sz7qMbwnD0T2OAm7SW7YjbDvZMDyUKpWF5KK4pQM3umbE3Xhll6ykmFXJ7agSpjCNpxJgHNGotoLo@eKV90pVFh0qePSvJaUdPdrou1lOo3HE0LKLwdQOjWx@lTD63MvFfy0sODmDIh5vVL5u8ILAIO/Rbu4wjcfAiL4XwPTmoMB4AS3A0SqIAfIyWQCk8osYW@mtjJZeSpH0FkfrcbE5GbVE6FKKpNcSNTo@FdFaT8xG1wfujAOS4I8WCILG@Zo6c0A2CxVnLVaRLChJkcSZFtdp859CSh1qm2YIoMdD9bN@yKY3Im8WOxc@PiJmC2TnjQHBPYjcqeCxZqbXk@nmkSQ2jeJJCKNRCWDAmTipLp4L9iQSSzpBSy1eVmS0JaOBI68lj0bYcg4NUCKhDNByHJRXTQQLoAhCXByeLAYor8Q4aDEd1CB@gjexJtpqrEYNWkwHNdbHAtZyGtY4aDEJurCv0UYZH3vN0C7b509eIYOPNdEZVbkztzsN@aRRTitgDYWwPExGS0L3vCMvfEdEjBb9qkB7kGhX16RHbJUGAv6NW5r1oQKK1TabIKuNEOJuYfBSXkrFfB1lsm8RY66Zxxg8h7jG93EDtEkQ5jQI9sAkG6KYDCnQqFNMsWLm0HCpWSgaZIwkLLF0Cp9nyP02l05Z3OHI71bJKpxZ3KxGbBeFPqlkKR9tbKixqIR@yxOp/xqy8YTDH4s4jkqUdM6/GI5pqFPxiqM08Lt82VlCXA0lrDUhHQVwethJ4MDXlMW@qIKA5vDiduCDyiIObEJRnNcpE4cSqhZxLF8ahxLYFnGUL98OkqfS@vLWpXGwIJiGo3ppHEiBi2NqLZ0CgjP@r5VGarHxQLMomdoudeKkoXG2Y1@dZF@UqCrQXpAwxOBnia@0dkjG3KT1gSEGXWo8UOhYHA/b45W0CUcx7dw1vmCuY8nCwnph4ZZS@QbWWHkNcS0Ie3AQVPoDvb5TFn9CRE9ckkiEdO@BQkylezwBEQlnsyKlD8WAEE5of6uFqlmtFt0MPd7fe3f/zsPWozsPUYha4j0Kr29QW4bUdWqVFYxnz7ctLdIpcgSqWmA3crQPG3nUPolmh04RihyLpZZODbgzixkorMmh@6LKyD0R9yGLgtYv4ETIir6bgemxqQ16U7fKL61CBGmeYKpXUl7bhJYQDNOJbAnBGMk5Q9ji8s9GrKHybPQsZMCOaLJNZnBotvcZGi4ZBYUov3wWfsWddFCXpKydlvIsogo@ym7knApVLuQNeoTBmMBfVavirnKKK@3X2oMuuryd9snx7dAbtIedXrsyPh7n@oEj3dPY@X6ATi5zqEy1e7Cz/6T1GON07dwjywn816C8g92HO3tPDzDnCWRdl8k7@/t7@y1SUN9/@vgAPYYmkiwTUGKJwGRCDOjR3nt3Hhgw/G3JRrJBSADyJvyRrnxKwhu3ZvTfOZl5lFgVokVBeMhMBYtSWkmE3tD1pyp4G/qfUAd8CS1P8FEG6lJRjckhjY3XnzIv8nV6ZkBROybTcUigpAFvJ0aiEC/BMMPgCAuQL6IA@HbSpq/wjTLmoSGfP7YTZdFABovlpH1XP6DVgcvkyXzUtRU66cizdOqOABJfm/LTsF9ey58V0KvkmJSGkoXzVTg5quQcNZ9eUo6g1ErPGUGMzGvXRk4ZvAMUWZTQJESWKVSAXxAbolj0Cqc5M0CUzIJdleNHnQrDhj4OI@PXXDHmiN2asp4v1I8Eon9JCxxNI/z52HyUIgKT71NkzNFEy3M9ZvRXdZZvmG09Oza9T0V23RXUHrkHDb4T2uzohXz2RXQnn7tkA1qYkZzxeB6gl29jssNUIdN4EDZgoMLJXLAFYRDq4YKeH@J/Z9K1axcVaGwguIIJa1mcy@4o0UgoCBmAxDxr01qP3NiwWYJWHGaIDROingbxgQmxkgbx0oS4ngbx6ScM4vXtYlFN3qZYuXGDtZlj85lS/N908XJZwW4oVeioMOAzi6vTmJHsMA4JXXTQHNQ8swG52bKb57YsjvrTfwfcJi5ZqkyVcMPPafY5mH/@e9Y639BdYpT@mntobFDInMgnLzZhxvvCe5LEVZOkLWkS20/OwWZZahbTy343oogPMojm05/GYNLJ5ttq3oUeP/XCdSUqW4@sGpII/mMRgfM6CFpcXq0v8jbKBryYvbKusageRAgY5LoJspIESavy1blV1kx89dQq6yZI7TJVfvozWac8v1IgfqghaK@Vg5kK@l@xhUaq@VAoDTRgSLSpeRy9@maCH8XbYBZLA38cYacih@e3@@ffSLY7KpkK//upxEkFTPpS05468P9wWRzXM3F8yCjK5cxxyzNEsZgJ8emPonbw8CaX2XmL5Od/eHHpWnbp341KR8f8pjq4mWtQyJJboFYPimdS0abGxvMHA6BTUlpjHKN6zRlLDs9iaTAW70BdZ0uLs3j2isqep2Zf19kJ5GfMYCkuCf3rEWO0wREGiTWKfpOVLzNcKnPTMbm2AnfI5HaZWZcG5jA2mseRpjgG07OZEDiWY0LGImqZW5DM3lmOuOBGqvATtCft41EbA7QG/qgiI4B4fnVn6D/38KCaVNHNReV5kCUNfRbWmhCQHOeg@HoHFSqgqdKpCOt@s9yOgO1udzqcDvANzZFyFTpGqlbRZRwJgqPpMJA48cS9O/UG0AMHObWIRQQxbwytpFMYWOlLVZ@oOq3axSqrVdYbr5AbOkqitnUn3jikypxFWQBdPhGDClV4GwasYuHRQP2UELErWkf254E3cm0DHqO4eiUjgfwiFB0u1SDKSI6JgaOEGiCPpsMYhlM546Qb43BOJUCLH7tWWsGRc5FuxMTFCCHaOsILxIr0QUeuZRCJtCCaxLGslFYLPEqE6DGQ5zAOsVpaqWFFY8wiF0XkGVprlrf75LaIjFoJB2HT0DQLwBFG6OW4btagd5Ch2@VYv/zbT/7OKpxWqyqNYup4ozbIDBSRJMKKnwf@Y/VtoEf5RNoqJnD/fYSbUffcrjdsY4Sa0EANxJWBGSYQMZ8CoaHTKn8A@41/ZBu@YFSFSFjV6p3tbXHw3v7e@2gNxZcIRAWJ4kgE68Iq8rBTyVi@VAxGEEkJizAPZcUIpBqxCKV7hWC6x@Rep28bGlgwWt/8Yxotusv3UdOd12UCIWZb7NQH7wlRt9ZEqydCUTDOwzf/iDH7Y9aeTUfsjy1JmPBz7ALxq6tIe6FfDJFe3y@@/2dUnbQoAZ4P71WGZtVZTD/lNuWFLNFsuX6Y2atYNTQImYgvHKJv/ZiQBRykW22EuSvmrqiRpHf7h38lCAc@PsDsGSVFDE/xQkTfZkT69YBGLhNf@UJ832F8PY9eAUxEnXm8iw/hnKxM0GjINpKrFwzfL74vWwzwXohvJufUsRxrbi51Mv7VnFkqK6cja34N/Jkz/AMTqTRzzcLIB1Uqnk9@Fi1Ts5vsOpnp@4qxOhNNS@3wJ/@ZRn2kYw6rBz2AM1pzqlLXSkab/@IvNf5Z7srsAoL55d9@70dRH2eZPZtl9ud70WqaLfZiltX2K4kt6at4ZFjFWeZU/DReTWzlzhzjMwvBT7LGfRYf7FnWkgfS14t@dsGyz0LybYVEL/jZhUs@C9d3FK7UxZ7sVsZyn2Uuc4U9Y6En8C9nNBMW47@Yi3F23sxnrvlssvgbQo4MHxqPLkxLtSo5nBqxthuiTn/RMy/@3Uy2xtz98KotYlwc4KgAHUpNMdpDqNmGufJPkzHlz5iviVLr0tmC6pFRS13WAqJJexCkVOU4n1tdKzh0IO6l1LL5ZpXkzqrVkctG99NxD6UOer8bkuQxoec/DB6QvjN@g@YSuG0QV9jahtwTNKnJh/SCEyyQD6Ijn0NK1EAP0D0QN@jvhu5uuc4pJG9cSWIZ@MwSXaHrdBSFMgURKUkU64epQgXLqakL4Z/0DsTSVYelKxws2UfyIxvlXLh5f@tHekfSo@THsSdQFi/G@Y9yGkjFiN7KyWOH5OmyUTuxLy1IxVPVEZB5dP@zuVskqsvmJQ2wLMzf/RN90LkB6rL2oD9o8koe/zE4Jg5M5glo7J/8kxDYheVoy8is@U/VxAe8Q2VVjifZJerJqObHf2AhaacPEmc3LhayJMZMGUvsPhJPn@zsi72nB4@fHuCFjOkYUcvg2YIei928L5MAG78kWJBlGyDmr7A4a@QxeXklr7hSoO7/@few@4y26Fg1yximc8v9IFaursqdM0Y0FZceITk@C@X50gJax3XL3jrOmhwhEKB3RyGu18CFHxKMLybY4bM825j82WTalLplxYznElP/eXbLuIzJvkzAow4nwKkLnD@n9iVlfDGUQVdWc3y9c9Je8xg/9EK5/CTQL5qCYjeb6Re@JycnlT6Gp5pOvIoboHuiAB3DVcdHwCyMfLrURLfZQHheF2RbdF447b6IfpW77dHLdoAKMu/MUCXauf32nP/msu6Ix0dDDsXxpvfEQtBtb2le6pYAWanTfVHqn/QaMoMNg7XCCSci9zNRH8NA/fLGfQ3hh3jPrrM6gxddf0DcrtUZwEFmRVVzDxXkXH3K77HHhjHqEnkuvZ8KYpptVqQQ@GhAOfATuCplXezNmvPDWPGZLh7TZgk4Iua5SFkhGPNZj4PCBsw4fxZVqqptzqSzeG1Chq8PqBSiIBHNXMHELMIxZ8ZK8Zv4QoVpCDmPpaHlT9eh0mq8@Qvm0VGEATQxhgF37Wrzg2fNZ4ejwD1ZPixWj0ro6AihO9KskcaUfPbwbxz9wcvB2A9iSSM3CFnBpaaSuseSGphWWPFFjlVC4waapRVuvGjQUDvQoUzcou@EtifNVEkb55iet62mFY0xN6wpG4Mj7SklA5mGD0@Gqb2J6NBAhOm6SyoSX5oulPX@BP1pKdgyjDk6gBnN0YwQAzXEl4qMYSrO4q3C1zJOgGFnH7iJrqh8mIpmIsvo5pmcf7P5V1@7@X1YF@mtJ4LlTTGhNDZzYcN15XJhj5ibjjGv0ILqcnuALv@snRG5p1GKg4XGclWZpnA92AUZdNaY/K50PMEvqSOphYJ1zVH2FXOHlyWvCzWkWtMkeoWnfEUIsjxvIBxBJKWYK4vNzGIg6fLGQc9iacVOjEbOqJEzLsLQs4xGHspiGMjTdNtwiE7b2nAeAb46a/SSWCiC9kuMT8WuiJarus5ozyEqUBaGMKFIZ93D1NqbRqONTSuBAAlxAUHP7beng3A9l9zw6mX9pfcoHkq1R/GXJAPeK4DAaAtusFKZrYlMvljgVbpHbi/hVzNn1Uu1Up3@V@P/WyWVqP5fX0ysxSHr8cRaKfG/X0viIY5sulhUr63ihpz71ZIYz8Njf7SSWxL6zBZ0ZqM/Qn5BfR7w@3Aw8sZjN6QwR@LIHeHjNgZ@9Xy8sUDnXxhXB36/cMm/yLpCLvgptvU8aCGilkRUGc@FdW3LgnEfjv1JKD4aeB31G2OU31xVX8E8QDdSgesSDxQAEySfuVHf92Ay3w33RngvUUWPyaHPvzsDv1MdgijvTsiVYwBrHiA8vzKZjqrkbsod9fBZnMwQ2i@gacdQHXSt1wKwFnbLLiDlBS66p7Sezfp9i5y3uIPeExcZN7w9EjqSym6P@I52cGzhtrYkHgETts7uVpQPE@2li0bcFXn5GFcecDxn0hjIG5G@UOMdY1mSZoaFStHyvZ5c/1kVeoCGUlaB2DK7QCeiH0bwSpVTFmDFkFgJ7CMG6WPGGM@KqEcYItRFyxLZiKIQMoHaEX3KSqMEqkiez14J2EPslbKidW2YVuYZ6@vo3hPvypx6Qe8UHtpJ1dfWMTYH9QQHFKdJPg3X1zCHHFQGAiPOsW8asx9FR7YEAHlCKBAi8NgT9MjQeU5KpHhZB4cH0l9F5eH1RAddog0oxgveX43cI4qSIk46HoeC6XkBAWDJ6tFH3lgOUSlGqp3pEbDatBYosooXBFP3xq21VWoQxTVSoD2/GwNdqQJmdC1bpcYdh8OB7sXt8FgM3JfugP2/cbMp9gsvSqIzW26feN18s0CkA0MZ6ymMgn27xGnbO/cf3DnY2S6Jcv0GgrOBqoa1jcHl7CLlkwGHJCMswsu30rm5ykRuB6X8VjVfkE3fMoe9aDZYIYA9a4Jy3NjOO1RM3swxYhCZerhXlXS8RR3bDXW1cblhU6YTjFpgqcFVK39pyUKSxrqWkARjmyOUKUSHBnzBxrMAlLlXwAjI3a2FQhiGEiLKtTaulst6Ta3TrzJsrOXyJtuZW/dADn8h8vvTUWy3zdPaaYs8bHLoLY@3tqt52hcqVkMcO/m3gnwDuXPNOb20p4VTFeJv1MdW2DxwB/7duZo/e6q0VmBACs36YaEgE/L/898g9p1FZgEDOyycIn/9kaNcwlZ4U99hD5p2nm@DodhHldCdhfdocw2dsKELdPzevEIhSXv34Ozt2R@ZdYztwilpN3cd53rhFKqcjNEOZQyboXsAGAsNTOvH0iKR49mzEbrFXUb566sPH7wHU76P/qWCsPnB4fK1aimfhyOeNJAcjPQhtvcePsabhEmhQjcK9yf@UI7LpK0rqeDDPloOU@tLFnatiqsQds4jN5S9D@7OD9pHj9pDkJjbMATxC5y2qfWDYe5Rl98cI8eKT65VOD1yCOp44vYbzAmdBc5L@6jQCOHPsVnFDajCWVkh7CEUctCBQGLUvRGc1u8dPHzg5DfaArE6KasiX@xo4gBCIYKxMYkE2hjpYDhdpKqQ7TaJYOBfMW9txvuyUW1v5htnZ5nteeC3e@zxKx8RcM@eliTFTZzFKW1MIiqYj10HE/hoe3fnwCpBWZR9MZFiHM1p02JnxI6qg8kNdwo6AudPEMZxVt9@m9KwyDRwnJVarYDqIWeAjXxAAFpeWJPG2aTt9Gw9kO2xV6Grc3fGdRFzslJZqbZHwQmwo9X6zdrt67V3/Am@G/TcoPt2AFuI08aQsl44fxsN@Umd7Mgf9N/uewN8sLq6ury25939na/efnJz2@52fgt4SOt54OMD/mRsNmDSPpHaf7DHTrpMXdSIEeDstqvj9gu/utqrdddqa/VbPffWDXetdn2te8O9frtz@/btbn91rdO7fat960a3U0W30VSkMiTlQYvJH6vtX67aLMZsbaV2u9@v12/e6t243b@9Urt@fbWzdqNXW13tr9Xb16/f7K2sdW53zufaovbkYINV@y6eHckd@K1s5i63sLfL0oX/BQ';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=
#*  
#cs
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvw/WWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 6  \=>axfnuen le._e=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Num un Cr Uu8 gutyIO
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>m=unsafePerformIO$0?error"<"`catch`\ErrorCall{}->pure 3;data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;_?_=pure 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,212,211]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a)+l 1e1+k+m+2*l(h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 34);instance Num ();(! )=seq;f= (^)
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

I used [this interpreter](http://www.orenwatson.be/tapebagel.pl).

The code is on line 60:

```
%++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
```

- `%++` is `tape[index]++` where `index`=`0`
- `@@*` is `printf("%d",tape[0])`

Note: `@@%` (`printf("%d",tape[index])`) is not used because of Cardinal.

Comment: I suppose `%--` is `tape[0]--`?

Comment: @CatWizard Yes, `%--` is `tape[index]--`.

Answer (score 6):

## 214. Haskell with StrictData, 10200 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kSH1NUrwWKVK8iFRTt5a61ZJal1Z3S/zYRbJIllSsqq4qSmSr9eHMeHHWx@MHezw7GHvWPmdmd7HzYGAHCz/Y8BgLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zBusFTImsvERGZkZGRkbeopqy3fvNb0L4YUeGNupqhsMcxXZY21JvFCvJNkbsuazauUw2EEComtUd9BXdsUuBEJMYU/WW2gY/c4xrRVc/KxaEZxgzLaNryX3m9GSHKXZLNhWbGQPHHDjM6MxPlmVsu29cqQlM2Vf1LoA5imVaikPxK4yd6Zrcb7blqZjcVIamBfE221K0L/0vDmsZ/b6st22AzDP22rBsBeFbim0bmHyVseG20ppCWgBQ2VKN/drBi6moImMvoIiyqSlDJjdtx5JbjmroSJM0Ozk4OzmaSiFJ7O3pzs50aIa9Shg62xm0rqejsuzMsmVNnsa/wmoDx9hzpsNzrNZVdJllksVkZjoyzzYseSbJKrMUud1RNSUJDcISrKdopmIxDGEdw2J7UCStkC6kG7VxymQL0xbGkdNoi0zLZp2p@mTSQHjD6ik6lDA9HSl5kVMRGS@irVIGsjViEbtnWMBHFhvYSpvdGlYbmEvXRtE4pGfDz6wp20p@BRFkPQTXunGrAxM5BjRtc@QoTDf0BCVGwBUm7TemGSuTw9Da4d50eJ5l9qfDVoHRWted2bbMFNixYY6mQ4vstbo/j52zad4RNo02tMZUnMSOZAiibCYJn81M9oIWtC50ZnZlQ8HaCrN11TQVh0cCrygWRUNqpqn6Ne/gR5bRHrSw8zk9BfLGDov8YAdakKrKTCEmkuhgIeIgDgYlODH6ir@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@FRrOxSXwdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1DGxAcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9pZ1ZFXDJBCPqHipLcUeaA6mGehtbHkY75R2krnFoA5rAR/fQHYyIKUAYP2@r19SoQAYGsKgqmLUj//0T9vdLuCptVog2wS7vmVto0Ujt0yFheGQIcOCQNWoWAAXx9x5csjgRtbUNgkIWR@JLKgQlOutMdDazIAMrVsVemlPvoGeDZ2r5SicyflgH2d9@ZpLE5VzLlS8LzehYSkDypuqnWDPN6GVWkogRDyT6A@cToElzG0WtlPfR9ZLkfXFSwUKF01Gl5dSqW4ZGC65TEHgCz/GOW9rE5LSdmTbUNsBc@T0DD3DEi0WbFUMU9Ej4Qkc4XjYaoajSZRykWhZrbSSHVVvR8JrwItVyDgcLbcqrQu1VC9PJfdnCWhuEQ12VyXSigYDIHKoU9yk@iDNkzA4vE0Ily/OsBtIcoxO@oKRMNNhNzwgRMoO8qWBDAJyKGlrimJG0kkpimIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwSa3HwqFwzF91wgA1nagodtZT1UCxpZk9HLSAKLptwkhgIe@2YKRGyWirDmiccdYkvqZRBCQLycRbJWwpOKR7fERdknc5TJ9AQSkwjLvQZE9W2r6ODEIA@rJjz0hjzbiFDKlMOMyA6NAxU7kLTQOJeUVqvCI8JwqZrBJXNABbU2GFRFOFToDdDWS64Hlf3QA8m@EwgI13Ep/s6csjwNLiw@q4wzC1A32pD@IBtKGWgjIHhI/CBxTMZED9zwYdG7XtdCKTy032sZku5lipWuIDCOnPqUd7Elbe35lQ0LCOcss0We8O5K7CNTEmt1qK6QhBBTWxHRBF0@MNBSbE4Jm0e4Gl59N50yDiqhbjPFDI89YTQ6GM0kUo@glQZxQmi6kKaI4WiCVtNJ07ANxMZR78iCATBfgYfKAIrgYATKYMldbAAakGDHzbU1s94Fksnc7lIh@EprOHIH/uINkTHS9rLIxUfZYJJFNeEBbjQRQJbNFZPDC4IqrqRAA1vj/gccyy3Z@D2PCKCAOBLzSZkpPAe1/B2Td0Yw5SIKSHFkEmY3g7gCZ2ggolDFyu2kWd1dMyvSaCNsOJQBv5r@c4pl2CcUJ1eoNmEjgldWqN9pxDHZkl5Vgj1TG4u6kZTRDLNvTPlJtDqjVoqsOpClGY14ZXduAGFLCOzSowcn8aANdFwh0bBCaFbyKwLypIgptQ8N8gABJQEggV6dgkindAqJyM9FYkmKSulIROF4yzIHbcIEx3gpjKo8um0UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9qo5zBSHzSeTLc4c6T/aTXhcOJ68MVY/chRcXF8OlcBUk@@LiOrjW0LWOrhi41smVIBfCJdFFKeLkwtgLSoFh9fD9hYt5GK1jsw1xVPqsmhH5olTK1uPyhSSeGXxGQdSBZAPoBD4ATzhaqaAzGg1Wb6GiyWZnsvabKJ1PWpZqCiK8lG9k7hdUyBIZ1L6J00hLKeMg@zhN@hULRkFQWlu9iBW@vEhf1i/vLtuxy/twHFNHy3KlCZWC/CL9ZNcyBjBcRi9WSgmpHo1eZGGQbFbC6fByJFJIaJCRHI1@V4jGZE7tSFgBqR25vAwDUQV9Llo9i/AN45lo1CMVlAMHZtAJI@HkXQHyb0br0VgY0kbDcZhiVMJhoEwLiWBTpZEzJwh0ePyKE2YzFgsQGxrWNX5nxD6EJWGCxZPvAP9unkxOe/vXIF1Zy9ZQFUlYXBsBb2qZB7bp4WlcJbZHGqsOwy3UAEbbtjczwtm4PiD9mZRbw58RTQcRgsJw7EG5qk7AIOKOOoQJAvT7kasI4fiNutAmTDgNTUmek2oSZNBxcNqrJOdqQ0d8WEm27DEPgN4DTlOTW9CxJ9FdBtklIAQ@T6Xmx0TLM4inVSWa1XytjjCwtGQd6ddWSWsfqHYPyQuaFU4lrA5QFVV20A0Uotoea8GY3wVKK0PV4To88NEJJtmV7UgUtcYa17pQ2UONAQvlrgHQcG60YL6jgOaAsXzyyLb1G9UydCRychtQA8OXsQ2mkM8jL7BRrbaX2XqYvvOQA8VmgiUfbf1Yp4nbslsspRua0TXYMgAgayaTnLH3dFwqAZ3Pgekls9XPRKBa19BHUzyo4HBvo44o5bOe9i0jZIrgk1cga9j8So8BHqjzyd6HbRghpFw6DeV3fWn6eJX0YZmuIwa22BhALNlqyDfYkh8UszeaWFBC/uCzSOAnQ@Edk8/rZRhQoVSih3@mpP5OzkOgn7tRbdc1r@7bpCHhUoZ/ljFRe1AGoZ@K6vBuAzUMTQVjqEuKCaQzDT5uXxRcl6kJueVNnBKdvuHIqbfJns3wJ4D6QkJlQTsVXgynEgn8DVIUy1RZqq3cpFBKCcwglU97AyWgtHoGC16C7uIHCoII7YESnoBKKBapeV4ysTgdcIwB6IttRVP7qrNHC2majkrReMB3Y3E9cIzgSFWcgJjJjAU3LnaNpbje5fDbQxzq7IBCT3ZwuLXdOKqd7laCqYFtpTS1CX2jrTT6oNJqih1k058QO1YAmUj/@Vo7NgynwhnhWmNf/YQwjZt8f6uxv7dxXDt@zwtBaGy1P9BkLEppaQoAk59QtNtffSuMHcvoe7q@LRpiKYukVyZ2E3DiK2JXMHYg9hJ84XkM7@P@QLIV6LZaLGFwrxcoAFcREPcMaHTsxmIISXsIXqCALBBK3EdIWk03sIiB3g7CxNr6GN28@IcTCcx3Uvoekdv6wDZ9NbuTJAq/cTod1Ae84AwFXyewE2nj4CwF8x2IybV/QZaZqLnAHr4Vwsd3Lubim4maC@zhy3F8uOMxH91UzDxQD1mekOEOyVxcUxFzAD1Mq4TJv6syjitQ3ENbKiKvudEPJvJwFwk3bruMUdEmjAhyATOcO/p8S8Ru4OrrmEcy0kQsRvGNFJZow7RnDUGQX77gFgsEgX5om@2kM3TGKLJ@FAnQZvgGixfPGUHSGnIDeuW4tG6IL4olNBBgUn6cOOclNqaSGuo42APn7ZrRGiACBr4u7Yb4o7xEvAndnRx/p8jwFrQMc@Try3cZTvy@KsSJr3dlOblJDqHeZU1Ecmqb7m7ORBzvlnwHp3HFlwEbYgMH24ULwlMY1PcNUMX2VZv2Vf2SMeBNGS4DQXfeM6HgB8cxmfH6I0vczF84DfoRkcwGsXpt4HR77Gqkk1IOsXgo@tfabMoOaK30MwE6U6jZGD5W9Jsd@pkDUBJrcjAs4iYTUuUl7ivgsqEBcwjllsBodYGQAbVUXU4d0wPXGeaVZ3LFZKIwTaUzAPU6BdM/dH8FLFEsEGSn2VQfAgW6YNHd59xKHg9gipNJriQldz6FK5Qwp@LLHad7hwQI/bc3s8zGJprCGVgOpBLP//yzNjTJbIP15BFNMjxHAyhJ3NJ5sP1EUvTQz/y2JpirgabKRBhyfQ1lS8adDVnzHPNRo07DEomebPVRlxfNDeyKP9DfHuE8XnJL0QZtxX3Oz6TEiMiTy3lMV/usNQeaYKdWHnlmNHvTDLlNZOBzLFWhRBY2Nm8GZchnGz5lFoTRQxnNWSBk4x05pzdwBvwXN@G@1oyqid@HiDABm87JTUlJGbbcVJVHmt2SrwdtI2Fed6nSWLT8HNhx/Zu4npXoaPI1dzbQOZ8AvIqW2u0qlvt8COy2B9MGmu@kbunxCGe4qhUjZVl@DKel8d@HQNxjMJ7jYTqpGv08oaE9hiIWaUEnQdLiTnvCRyZ1irCa3BzhvK/37ZyFGZLOCnKm0orF0lkcZL1tlfGevmk@nB5HZkpfLM5Pzff4OUnmzVlSfG8/wde8qM5it/8rnRyGLrUva4lM2@d8UIq766lj1xxQWgRItDTZBmZyRHMoN9B89PMYg@No1EK2GrseYe9xcdzdtYc2akQvFT25ZWiqjd1Ze0hqTq9tj/PEUxb0M06KvlnCtkkNtnsJzzVfEhgtB3dJHmC0J0g2vkGBW0A@zkkaDxGtZdzi90HlomfcKPx3/uD2eW6pniCjEhqxhNqaK0Dbra9xKu600898Ol7PLZfT0uaGi/2AyanAU3nZVjXDhjk5/j5GCtCubZv/zudiP9VUWU/QsrXfPT@ZKJTJkmKZ7oG2lLWuoeUL3ZQMPw82@MDqoOQXz6dKPE9iSdLXJZarBxm6JJ4PivrrlHX9NU6gtW0L98B8zkfG2XliS@ydPFxBmD/gxvb8yu2kC5QymeILJA81gNXq3coj9/kTRpOHqOuOJuaI9GpQ8zBBsQAOx@K69k/JbeXx3NpPE0kzaFe/Vglf415rCgxe9DvTpCyTlr4xhZROP11AdbSBMlDmyqfD5pWCRxsfmW08vVBpUY0lsZSYAuLhQqIH9VnMGp9Uahy30feogJE1FTr5V7WbufLOBF3cxIn2ETiO0DGbsKsPzInGnZit6cePU65nuj3baE8UEmO@VSIVvq5DTajrtkLfh1T77b4Bc2OjD2qD/oT2F0hp1YP/TiCmkLGiMbE4Mjd7b6McdFlQPaBF1Ws7geviTxM6mYcm9ARcLKZ0VVecEf4@ROl5QrRpGNq3tAzI0rZKR5i1BB5a/VoLzag54swEGy9d2LgM0uw8tGjBxxkxuQTq4bzZeWSm7F@KemQ2OLOs/sho5Vtk/9r8EkZqWhWyrZbrfoghafFDShaSq4@yI9dCjaaiyfwxzK88hq@YzD6Kz9M6hHpLmzK4kcO3bsa7aqEp0WOOgFhqG@YmPaWvkPcRpV5uXw1s9/Eg0NDA75zoZIo2Ih5IZ6rQ13X8ndgm8mlDjqHDbMqRra6C0xENd0ZF6EPy1d3fmEvcvb7cVfgNh8dEx3hVAg/T8Unc2Dl/faLEz7e0IBnf/n@cFaDjXCsj233ORfh61IL2HPS/vqo21cdbuPr51U6dTM3d1vmKuqf3jJ7eU3oWdQ7P91D3AI50@N2UxyoB5e/J9jWeHiR5NJ7N9Ww/dTVD055CXZSHXDoaxvyF2W08@d@GpN@EdyQ3IUI8vrpiB0M2EYnG7of6Tk8ZwMhkG45hKgnyPQSq4WIP/52/1rx3GLbZuapYbX70AdRxyFptagq7VaEIV7Z/33n@QlJTM2Q8oPqI8g6UcZ9PWZpqGdZX1z26suGYJj0apjaw6YdWdBN0T2NedXeopE9hBtXhp044yypdo9nqqV8rUlORHV29TrlrONz76LxUCGOqucoSWxic1FSglTVKIhNU/PEn@Nh7aPzzbeHMrf3mwLJGXxcMkzv@3lIr3yFAx0P5i83ZOdE05OOxKvf40CPbFGIv90FuIgUaleWEkgatRHpwBWjiBJmQXrSp@IDSM1VvKoxvH@1bli7FYQBaxFN9BxogfN7ixUOCcFfIN5gVRnYHXTv6dcbttUGnwp@5CGtdvKzFd5Jszbj1LTRD15d18Zg7Knu7jo9tgeQe3QNJpsReZ0IZPLi6pammzX9ZopOZi2V2834WajR/piuap610@DYFur6m2fUNC4/RgwqRaFmK3cIVb5S@XCpykaMbXZDCCY2NgV3YuVWYPS8wTzeZHOES7w6UrozH6vZVPGGn2bODHmCePjrwFMRvBrKtvhkYjjIX5/QRgqegfC131dbuRCu4CF3qijNY/DHRCTBotiFue6pNp5ldx/yOw9mMduNnI6cX1b1bdY8vhPj0InGolCX2mHv41HPgsj7Gy3PzmtQ6xUb8g4JOdWjBVDzn1nP@cYvHVhFuB31zYIvH/Nz7eDfBv3Lcv6Zw@1YFKZj4BEKX9WTNmb@67Fs8BX1KjIRj50Na9gdVM7rsQyHNQP0CAYdK9wOMtQHj8pHsQA/Q5zAr5f/EfUtcm0hwpcb@BIygZFlC1VXn8XUYx5FhHuQ@sUJc1cK7N6l9/E0@/1YMidP5VNl/VOLDkD5qaTCz@RrU0fuvQCibXx9avrLtAkOloQ@cBN5XfGyIyD86RJTYsJD38QCLvNl@fRZ1WaHba/GzjF/RxGwFZnQDWxuNXQ9u9s/hMBXvaT8sZGdTuFODLaUjDzTnGHf0npKuZpoarmyATN8y5k1hjkYwxHzTPAhGiUF/S2nhTuCTynBgvAb1DMYtE6Rq/1jBrfspQfJwYky6b7RkDWjWflJ2J4R@Xl1PZVPZgDbXvrG@HOOW7MgzWPk5o2O6QutdtrLj4owwhKmWuOlpJ93r1CE6T01Xr9yrOCyEF8IGqNQ5hpVkBBeJyLFYNBrgiXBjrKsDmAtFF1rxshu/K2sz6DsOwaoddnHBlu6GpXRJumcVFiwFWb3OseKHrl5tD026jXrMk18syfXKUjiRCC@FL/USS4c9cEWD4WEuuDwB21Hpwcs7JgHTZX5qHt1ujcv8Mp/do4uyMBVqw5TqTKeVTpye8Stp/L7jKZ68@eu/aIv7w10FKttXQUUDguD1eaOv9IzbdZ6vyB0YX8b7x4gDRnON34ZLbNYYDDMw9@LXho1bdrZzWhCXEcVdffAccd3cKwVvXFz9w6sEDm88XhrvWLjI2EvlVgqE2qCvw2y37fTsJDtR6ZbAwBofygUXgumOhVP@dpztsbaCBx7o8getcmmGcU23uLAkf/0X/AomXQERR/Pd7OnqtS9HvOkh0b3HVssYQKldJJ8VyxAgESQyjO0DXD9mKO4pPIoXI@huKHBkwr0ZSdnw65GbtROW2GZhNEOAF67KaieyVDt@8fYiXa/8wPop5T//LBW9E4QLfpco5u1gnLkg5XtkLH90DqLHsWEWXBoGeYbe/RhVCKtb3h5AIpkzGV6RcXnMMEzRa@h2O13m9rhRWFmJoJva2b0i2aeL8cSwyi1dkaTT4zqKKrxxrtvQwcAbJdS811WWIgO@zJk4cVgOMsRrpjK4@FV6ujGC1/0wydKQfWE9ZLJEC28xgI8TUsMbpv3KhnsELus/qJjaUpoDOpxzk0lmshWqzlKjslYll6W0DbzpffH95TCTTlwOV7frKdsl6uXl8Lt05h1Q3bAg1bMU9rztg627pWQ1/eWLLY9YMHgfLvODlSAmlu6O9o62T05rp2cn0Ar3rvjZMay@PJY1yEV0L6FnaHSHHuhiqYr9DfLH8wF4JMKWZLaG1mGi0YD/YDyBCloHE8El7vSJponUX0k@L72t@OJnAYRM66jM5ag9GDSwDYHZkGpY@YGJlgCYSCtuMxOXqSjjsQN5hMHjq3NkKZEqyCpArAQQ64mkYg9Xdp2HPYViX8XyONnW54Igxbz8Lrx4XsW5JLj/ndTbhIHyt683x/J4vQnmkXoDqBfqptmp7e2fHW9PJgMeoydJ3UoxJ26EcOGMPY2vkLrXt@lankiIS8SVIAtSAu4VgxmZ/mkqzq0C1RLCsdXniYlDqfzBwJgxgTIVtJ9UL3NaRCJUAtRBylitqQsrHXXoK6I7RvvQ3fEqekJgJ@ihdgueDArMIbJlk8SPWw3EKsjldr0jEuJCXodtv/oTd3scVg3HaJh9UqoHhipv1LEZ/PtGJdeVqbMhE8OZVGcJloGvpuhdqLALGy3zMYotcUIEl3jZg1550Y4KlKl9JdNKDZ2dFHdyYJTWZBONNgjoA8NRSuzTwKCrha4w8fSLW1wHkLnJIGraloy1oSuLuoMGGNxxi/Dt7ZxUUDvjqhnJdz/PDXQcqADIZ8AHJhkW2lrqkKznpkA4yQ1hdcIdKmnp3ha3zD0twWY3qk1L@9gIHdRxNJCUWBtRcbSeRZdKWU2zQSdpw/DNbU2RcpKkA/78lH9CZ8EQ8GTSUxnjLBhAWLsya4UAhtLbFgyrH3niJYIjzLYPZ3htMZEAynVV3bX2VMIdCFqaLTHHGuA5mWp4JolbhBK5Ej2nr/kA59hjuVRSP/7TP@U2WC4dcP9CuIfpDfD9gfB1wP1P3BhJAt8/83wZ8P0h932fwiabNTwhshcT0wdvQwBfPg/O1AllgmvyiuritTa29Nu9I2bTNgm2ZV8e@poJJQzynKoDvdQ@MMUNtTGC8xzGTTjGE7l4CywCfAX8geoNajSUn2LVI2h@oJRKYcFxLSdJR@iVId8jIWsEnwZohQeUsFQ@l1@RUlDIxI2LkK4Ed/EQN0cYjZZAJgZuVLPysdnCuzksaMMkUqnky5w3Ukvy99ngR6@gSwAb4BOFCwZp8DqPlwLiqiJZZEmOSVFMigNZWAqjTGsbnNVAG4yQA0CiGKy7Nx9B3TQEqYCPdWXokMY0cidATbS2hmu7CrfF5CJKACKOG23FTHfH8bFsvMbi66BJfzMEzxHsBMFKwXnMevE9u3Qu9bqwGcSA8X41h3V1cP/jOYaEOGfhJelZCzaRafszWBv2/EQ38Pj@DpSWRTKpTDYl5aM@Dg0KVFBe7OpfACV0bhAWLUW9Mky7trm99/Lw6GTGEgtBhqfBwixcXYtdJpLxi7rnCHvlniTqxk7q5PXGjktKf6nGJ1wQYnzMZbqY83KbLukDuZ/z8/CzeVPETEZS@qmIaU85sUOnwGaxj2NTPsBNfhx3JtdI9O7@or5WvdRDM9l/mWedKpRcRuYC16VNtqnC08XEIu65p/xP0eqlnXSve2WCY9tr3iU17h8HP2xLxbOhOTao4t4nCNCF5PGl5eQDNw2g7skUz4qsifCCueUFWeMWVcKijjNsBWZOKflLw0RdZs19iht3HpEO@RqSa6zR5pA2CWe@ykRWjTyaeXCnLkbs@mMTJ8K2Rw9Kp6nNwK24hu7eV/SuoCdtU1OdSDSgC4jpm4uzkPajlkI8MLlyMWTeFTwbdcZhkta4I2SI67Ye4IZWmGsPJUYmVY4GQLcjw2TjVbQtxXUdg07FtgZ8zVNhLwd9gOvQ41jB0UIBLSsBiYGeYbcoF2hERFAi2W/nIsNosqcM22oXRpxINA6i6TtJGhtjkdGaCOhVzXk1wGUpsydDHbBpsmtoy2QYXSuSd1xBvvrIbucH6/UAIMOkzWiJr1yEz3TXbhY2fImF4x5lmtF4OMn4TEqYxKKTFrQQlWSbPTyXSksfnY5KKpvfxAEfzDuq1U9irWCY4Sz0Ak@l@7nmm@zi@CgjX8hJVW8rwwiaICjVkU4QHr49vwlHgzMsTsZ5hCmW9rSVHlcWyo4QSmMLN1Pyrlj05NykaCgW0YwBXuaESQnkeOJY@@AEFSHS6csmiwzIzJHNkoy8kcuIHrcdK8oSVRyub5nOYjFa04AHRcCcBUE75FLJnkQErQJGUhVoJAy19TY@Pqsmu5CSyTq4KZMoW8L1zE3QpnAlMBqAOSokKRFa0C/gr4Ql4jZck8KW6xJlGyBLIwA1N5rkFG5ngHwBWlCtWfWZz0LDWMBwqhaLJdEak9K@yIAv1uYIREA7R4q7cwSgr7iNB1RDGQ1Qm5bSVkFePn@l6LoCBAKe6aPJWnkATGZF46415fjY2iHlEOJF3BXX@6Cgk1YQt8N3Gu4SLKXKtDRWvge15uMl6jUdodmMUv99Kpkq30WWtMooBbpmtBpZ6lWkWHY5FlvSlyNLOmpbz57hitr9EihzjSRMUIcAlFjSomXgZ1D@Kkt6eUleiyy1K5llSgFemCLfQYIf7FTybkm@Ty09A2UpDiEWFzqRJZsMFKWTSekeyoc9ZCkVB565Q0s7ZCMZs19SYzEsQ3KpgQX4IXV5EqNh8/IkRYt3ZTEXSHX7ortNqWJeS8zYduYEFMElb8DK4YAljmo2XOCxDcTsvLgH1D@e8Ss80M7oHI5i@ydfwcmYpwsWIadR5gohE@EWooCAwwgQEb1xORoFYfKb34SkPGPB9Xw2YsTWc@lyLJyTYJoO8@vQc9DDU8tBK3h3uZW4YUonk/@UuJA7yU/1o@ujo3fRywgrsnBo8zAorQS/RzPWT/ussswDH/bTP6HQcioQSi1Lz1ZTqY8fP8KMAz4X1WQVxAf/RC8S4fpFZJWx6urqcjxfWI4/Dzd8xYpGMpnoCVPVFLtUTbvdhq/RI4PmkRD/rK9TXjD9h3/Gw0T@wuF6EESEhr4R7kbOhdjlqiwvx1Yyz/VyMpPO/PW/W7yP3x011v769/opZREfh/j4xf1rdJ9Iue8WF7/b2FhZiQMhufvow9H7Wq22shXPHV3k1lcS6cW1//QfFxczmbVMarFu21I9fHH9LphJrwSTf/3n4aOjNw3bBkIU8ZNlEjjxtwBfieVy7Jp9hs91h@E/uT@3fW4Z3c3OZ7QKBfOVCgmbcDiXDZ98H57fbItMqq6v/pc/OvwUckLVTOrcgqcT@hTKF0LcCQ7wZV3fTagaWkOw/H1olKpUKuBc/S//B6SvvgQ8GDNag59qzsWVH4WqiQol@RKq5sEhZTKQ7//9s58FQtVh6HNIkqTQiP4a6IZP4Zn0jKEjFVwtBA3jOZpcx8/Q9xnXIiVJmUu3PX3NjU3rBfcAN7QrM3xhXrt7XMUEN5DjqXBV@NnGz9/827/5k7/5I/r7E/r@B7TknV98/nGLMQVGYPyUSs9n2mF/yn@cTMAn6fWOEHoTomahQiXe4KXyWDjkc0zRwftlgiSe/xvhAiHXHC3KofpEY1yGpMLK4fPhkz9sXGiXtqExSb3M2XSY2xieh7mygH0LXCD0Q6Vy7ODf6yb@Hdn4xx4t8iMGkdg6fBbhj/7h43nxd5FCRDCBzH4WfwvpGwhdhC7q9V0d/z716M/Cv@Yn/Nv/jH@fHPw7beHf8Sf8O/2Mf7O1CYTW1tZCsdgxqIyCaZ/yOYNvMtkQPo95Q4HQ7/TDVg7zh88D0CfqscT9/UXy@2GsXBb/oEyVPR9@uAuKVb9PJNa@r8ZiF1S8i6oo51qiXoWy8iLTz/drgDi2drG2lmxUq9VE/fvqxdpkIpHu@fMYdtTnkLBav7gIhO6wLSr4s4w/LRt/M8FgirxfUK7DQF0MhFDHLXJVt8gD6E0U6AuEPt59jMTWY@tpLX2Tlq6l69fG4fj/8HAIEeowfWVY6V66J7VBULK0cpYepUfDdN84lNrgVOAv3Qenmu4M0920ntYlaTScQPXwf//QcF4fGoDNgJTOMO0g4nQHnt3Dw9eArwN5X8Gfmk6nh1DIYfoG/tMaim0yckfP7xvRO/h8vP94eX8ZuGDBjwpoB0kpnEyHk/lwWK3n8uanYDzcuLwI18uhlH15meJ6E8uslMnK4f19o7F9sNVopJCT1pZiz2OJ5/CpVGNr4rEeqpbXL0sJbEHOgclGKLW2flnNJtCdj0EzZSBsLRX7xs8YJTyri5cBmAqen@P3/PbmlrvIQa5LDD9v8Gj4piiIvBQEn5vb1HwEEw4GSujf03/78L@u/9dnLHJRjzIWubtfi9Anin/R6N393b34rUYjEeGJrMEfBoAfk9zdV9FJQHfguohE69H7ex4Gv5HoGkdYxTzWqpR4DAh9NsRzvQyXGYNJU0Tst11eDtPpaLkJId7Ku/yFtm6iZTrUstTE7TaYKEjLUQLJrZTLK8K9WiiXC8It5fPl8rIHlQaPcAKQYsutMnJ6OWRGsQyc/yNpXG8hW7LhSFvp4EsF1k0TJn1SMf3lixfUaLRVq9HA8OyXL5fQlcJ4pqVSzEFIuvDlC3TEcBQmhAeG2E0twvROSmXG6HuyLTuOFYEpf/wyjEf97MtwFOMz6TQCY3qWW1vLr1Sr@RVw5wvRaDm4xA/ERLqxohS9X0oFeTVgqhYOiSipsBql0PswxrPQGluvAofb@GF39yGiNlvJRSPNkRL1AqRikYewlXykECuKv8pilKWqy0z8XVxkYyvLq8vP6/XxQI1ionwnV6T7yp1cwuWD@3JLGHLFg7Xys2fZIpClkC5fBhqNrdpprYFvxMCtaRDDDANJ4ARw29G0whe01pMr1i@wIvXLcLhUfs7btZBjoXBZwCXCILpYoUj1DcGEUu3gifohYEW8gVBJWs5kF1O54Xf57TRMhJbxc3FxUcgUYssg15aLxXq9TqFrlOKiP@zUyZhXJXEh5XP1BKovV8POcshk0mo2tBww6YDRapq1cY/WwnWzRQiEJmVN3E63FU1z7ebeGpbWvlXbymIgdLRf29w@jWfWAGVmp7YZz5ycbYQk9ObGforOov94u7Z1eAYJjva3ayfbL/bebp8dQTha2YRP/0hWBkpDuR0MbtHfUOizqdry1ZVsmg0TPsPOj7/6@Y@/@h9@/LM//PHPfv7jn/3Jr3/5Jz@H71/A9w/58w//TTGHv7/@5T/73378138Ggf8Bvv8evv/u17/8Fz/jX/L/FXz/L1/YX4mvD45/A4DrD379yz/681//8p/8S/j@K/H9l9PfH//4/@T//0n8ofPPfvzjv8If4fn5H/74@3/04@//3o@//4sff/8fQhP93V/@Cv//6C//7t//Cv//9//l7/7yf/q7P/hfyfGn3PH//Kt/w3//9vd@/re//8//9vd@@cDvzx/9/eUTwn/59xDy9HI@Bc9T6vWtIb/8SeX5bagxzgV4ALjuH//4L/4R8O0fc9//CD7496J@4Xm8mBjN6RKxceAvGPuSAr0p/fyLBwoo/2cMhWD2ZRIbhabd0F//8p//OQZPwP4jP4a0NAu7hMBebr8A2H/tFcwP@4sff/WzH//8H/74qz/98Vd/gJIssVKM1@IJ6SvLQgCYewIcAuafAgeA0hrukC@yxUAGHItruIwRkGIfPwJJF8EF6vdyIJcFX6her@Ln8iJVvUxdVvmnDv5kqoohydRlCuOTKdDeG@w7mO/g9/nzZfZdIsGf47CAVCXUUMYYCHQJJkfLfFUihnND@A4DK0Xw4TpFDMahGI@KQdRGjFUqlVhgWIE4AgUvphmyagFnnTgBqQBeTMTTxBsFUG3ZcIOwQMpK7Jg1litDnjCGAVXCwLBAGHQclDLBWKGyBRlWhlsMcSHyWOAjPD9WqoXKsIrofqAiAI7YBmQJUBUs3bD6A/grhBPgA8OtH6AohUosVi1ASIWqSrnFG5SnlKPKUd1jjOqN4TAbhsf6c8a@C0qFIJ8IQsswAY2/sTH0Oq2HrEP8ZWxZVIf@XSd9lzE9NPuQ6MPDePw6BlN6AQB4Ewk8nAVfaEYAeA7RQ44qRtnCI8YxAOViYnrvBZAWEAvEqH1j5IH8oQxP@6xVfR5Eh9VZWloC11o1mA0ewnyCWdcl25Et3LsgRanEgvliEIPxrIuydEQzjuWtZfiV4H97kc6rcnIsB5bCqBSEmZtHIpY1VowQld6tGtVlmUoeI7hAaBzOlVzagALtdIVFAxEyKR@liatimvB8bXc3jCEoovFgMC7l@RJzVMxr3xulUuUHaWU1AE/yD9CavbCrDs2AbzhLYmdFglbvEmvUccEJiks@UK2KTTQmBaon26eQ4PSQSZl0koH2ereymlnJreQy2Xw@t5qRVvLFlXyukAWBl0/nMhmpuLJSLBRX76lIz0FwxEvLzdxa9R/MfP67fzDvMz8UP4HqOzZMssR9oDpMJFIZKnFFyq2WRxUoBwUFqqSScT19dJfAs5OBSzqrdYfHgqBYgbsEsukCfFhgIcAWIAg@gBa3D5jY0947LIvNPXxPCN/gC0o5YIRo4BIYgWMLmJOfADbbM5A1zyTuzOXHzjQ6T/Ha2gHkAI2gs308RukY7NTgx/U2lFZgTVy4qgYCtBdyASStB9AM/0U9sJbyYudj2uzxl@dtWgaouT8dZkPWr3nUlsqv2nhRuzLawrL7qtN7AOLM7OOlGMX6e8Ow3W9CAXHNkwNswI@lGcY8gFV2dvRALV9712BxU5HuwQL48d6L3VPf83S7trkbyLONw4OtqUdOAOXY/vbOqedd5bFu0pyH4v32/v60VzxwqrLIcqvxOEhH@MFnnD70TC5974JIyUcWPGFoSq2xJZyL5qC/47tYLytVedjRB8DdMNFqKKxR2biQyqF6tQBCZmU1t5pPF1ehtx4M@gOkBDsbFFh34Iz2Dlm6DOIGT5QVJX4zQrUDuzCv6aNBfTTG4AQspQ1znFudLn008bVYA5M9GAgPDEKnpXZ7UIJbwwUINGWZwfdbP5Be8X@cxwMcngeFzcRoc8BxD03tsHQgSetfmWIhVyhmM4V4oVhYycH0LxeXMnFptbBaTMeltFSQ8oVcUYoXVorZFRCIEJsrrgZCIDjUTioF8l4KBump6i00eruG1oONZK8aCPHVAxhk8X2PIdkLgCYJZguXaUgXDOBpWaZWFoP4RtU0vq8UEMqsxUI7O5vpnZ1gcAM9uNy3mQ4G2@jJFdLp1Y1gUKGYTZDZmWDQ4GkgCsAc7kmnNzaDwQFHgPd2g8EeerbzqKsGgyp6Nms7O5jPFXoymB7ArnkM92iuZxXAdPRks6TsBoOfPHQAV@MZrVBJt9GDeWLMDo/ZhLhg8IVbnnQaMBxzOI5h161rrRYM7nFPrYYxL6niOV7UV@ip0ScYtMADPBgMdsHRtWBCHgw2wYmcGAy2wNUayRCGBobxiqfuyMHgiBMISRQMDglabl0HQZMS4ZjN7u6u3HPaSpd/RhZ/tqBoEKMOB9s7zRcvmt1u0xrVtl8cY8zLl7vy1WhgNbtNkazZgI8BaSDmuj@a/kAZ9xoNWZsb8wpi9KmYxqihYNka8icok/h0MZN@4yXEvISYeZsrHBt8@gDaxM9GH54bcpNi3A/F0HPYbAbLyKPOyFRwlQW7DJ06KvtD@nLLMsroAtWbLYYj4fjoQqrHP5cphvUZi0Tv0uV7BOlE6GUpKBlBz7kbXQwr6Too3FIZF4Aii/31IIi7YGlRXo8M0Z0PlkDlXglGS/iiGaMTZuGEtD4oBPOrwdIyPIPrwSw4h5F0OM0Y/EQvVuvrwVVEElxfTwShLOAFEBkSBleLiLC4CsN/@R7o4cBw1Bw4SqMRidwq8nU0yuvEX07Fzs/Po3f8pJVKdXTKncgwPqzw0jA1Wv4MhZ/G1MZbrYOWY1gcXxco8Hk9XaJKQvYFyp6lUtE1lEgoQ@D5kVawk6yU4O9lkQr5aBIPZjeMToPekMA@usvc5@czLv5h/gBUDc/xhgXdrnSP4pBWbJcCp6g/0osfGd6Wb@K7kuj6K0xMuNkOerORAtpkMRCoCoUKL74mdwY61i6Jb29yyiLmVBk6yV0FD8y03LBNfo8xuT3EFxyqhu5GnIxAK@gn9w6TZ7otd5TyXeI8cU9XcPFGJF70VdtMrlTBJbcjlBGTo7dU5ka1WmlU@krfdEYw/yAVuOqlhdGPbTAOiXcr3OPlMFpCVdJlHc1a0OC5NAwNA9U2XuXdqGzcDUolgL0vKxXFsgwrGAqWO@t6ZUAFPFIsvAmxd7jUYQpeOWj1Pl5uI9wmUO3uPlG1mF7uVi4w3y/4s5YIBuuJxMWXOii6lXR5FJIr9qBJhhNYugmaeL48hDBpdaWsQVX5dZIlOlQml3usWWl@PyxfV2C8gjwzLL9StirmwFLKn6DwFozoVPItSLrVgBTtCDwaUYoh7JWLTLoYz0gwlMEQBwHwXQX/Cnwl@Gbqi4sRLSIpUtwxtnUgW7pUQuoB2ckLTzkayyxrkbbB5LUEtQJ0qDKWArpxj5lqvBeBVMeKrHHwaOw69mk9E4u0k1uN6Ho2wbLFaNnfOJFoObIYrdjKp3KnEvkeFHFS9r9ouMa72Kikudq/ZA/6F@nFvBS/SzQS95psO0vSaqZ0MVi6SEhQ9PSX7lrwQzVYByLfB2CG4F@ChjG8DGFu3@Kj/njcHoeZZVDHNAWaRCpmygIkYIoeHgmyCL6RjB@vioTDq5lwOBouA9QiBJOgiN5Rvw6DtAk/AxkDegMImWIG4i3FGYCaCtJvpgR8apOXAqH7QFu1TbZSDITuAvd392tVVwt8xUYjOZZwvc8Y68ZgkpuiLbNkI8QWyZVIVp@zWqXWPa6VBWhtk6aiqQC75Jf2EqnFb92Yi61Vv@fPS9yWhWwCnDi0e51ai1VTl4FgELuJ2FGJFHJRPgX@IUQ2QdnmXQdFBXT80muklVw6IVP9F/XoDweqdlfIJqo0OwKmuL8PxaBueC6jmiJKtQ7pOEQgpBvCiYvsDsgZkKK5XBBnygozT4rfr35f@P712eHZ4Q57ni4VSgVOhks@eY1LYSkMM@PnoL6px9uBkPnFyEk/6C/LoZIZzq6EsxPK92VF3FePIBNELnALCr71C5gD16PgqlSkdWm1pNpihyhSsgemYkXXpXymlElL0ZB9j5dpM6shekr51VA9xFGurEbBTXsbGSlUTYlgaRVTJbgPuDcXsotfQpl0IRAqvP74hTH3HcpqhlyplCjs0v3aPfxX7y9g7n9PSwD39I8/Kfi55wD0jwlcDz3Gnwm4Mcw4vv5DYo3/r9HP5iEveTAPDRH6CH3ftr9vfN8IBULFMExewiyTE2Ucimk1KuHLOv0p9jL@fT8OWLZte9nzgXcZ6sxyVYmB2p5KXUbfZEBhLxbzhXwo8JvZT2p5IcCWF2oszM1u8dEOjW56F7bCE281w3Wb5YXE1snh5qvtUxzuFB3fSss2Dw@SGIUvTh3fuGtpimxpI/Hm1BFC4Sh5unnEDJhpbR1RmnO6a0mhtDwjclnaa5fE64XiN0xKZnHfL5dKr6SkHJMKpfRqKZNnMsghG20rCNcSJmVUrU3DHPFpVmQzSokXagiDcfsqTHhtpcReHO1TCjK7sLywtf36kB0e7L9PuqE8/HR374SdHO6cnteOt6Eer7dPWLB2wvZOgux873T38OyU1Q7eM4g@rh2c7m2fIIJUAGUYqn2cYN6ch63ZIzuFOqFNE5@JYNtoXSvOZLhsmXIKrchOBuv4ThkF38QwGT7QVZhV@edUJ7UFrmAxRC@321YAL3mqLbaAE6qFZRi/8Y5pL22vstzg3ee0lVtkrZWD8CprpQ/07Noq09Lij2kr/ewxW1xcvNSD3gDgr4Y3pfMH4fUACBuXae/D9kIkv8KWYSKXWYmOYw4OjxbSrm/h/Ph0QfLijrcWMp5nb2ch63m2wbfi@XbOtxZynm@j9mohP052sLmw6vm2tjcXCp4PmHShOMZ5sLUgpQMusW5AxVqg9@ZFdvb2t9kyAEXLE7G4aIaOqWAgRATUIm5xg@awy8u3PSNOM4LmaAq6rXwN2gWfgFpA9eYC6VqPs2XDhB9Q@QAYkgU8FV22uq24wIoWl2BkCdwFFrBCC1ghgF/Au94IxxYrLBNlEL3Q4UcQItwCX5wFz2y60fmdzdZQ164CM8TJhBPd7IUUiniBZmDhXqCMdGhhsUPHlQkU5j0saAWjUbwOeHC2v88zM0mfjAQJknHlcg5OwwRsUEX4xapDKG8c3izUFkirBaFV4Es@A/cTrRmYbk0kBdRzYaEFCCapeyNrcYZaVRz3txEvevg1AwCGaHCnwcXvQUYiLaxrV3FaVKAoEnP7cIfXEHfIK2yylaMMMyVKUTS/wPDlC3N9l86k15r06mGOWyDnxeL4eEkrCBvFsAX3AipB0GV7SrmAHBOLQWqoDsX56rUARIcvv5vvlrIKGaXD7NkzKsca@IphygLTxShHlkAQRCAIRuRDZF7RFqm40YXUMp5doZMsZCUUxxFu1LU58uyKgGSdLuhUq3q90GvOBR2mmOUpgSyiOm1sa3BnMw3wo3gETo6zJnSTOHMjpTxG4lwszpQ460DwlExtqDpwrmKNZaLLCtAZqfUPtngLcSM6FM4DqMYg90rUYCAsnmH3JUZfWGhaMNEuu1AgDwkK@BaZJoKE4HCPpzveomTLvL8gW2Lqp6Tc2ym5fMRTAzsITiOyot0DziuiuhRYHQPN4BfIsP9WAD1nSY4sFhMQHpcJsO1JuESCw927fPmVSmxP12Lxm2uBYvnBWmw/sRq/XS1gWBuzCNQCRHwE8MYAmn4mWzMzDwWMhYSCavPTUMAAOuYl6OMTCJ6QHobccfrEt6eHQbo03ZWh30ILcqnAk0x6W5Pe9qQXuy@EyAzmBJkV9oU10SXlwYX331kBHG0uKycTdia9tFRTYYqbpuNJYJ4D8ByKSg6GDDgrjFGCJG18AYXcx9cgVVhtp7F3sH06GYv4knZDFLznGLpGeUQnwUSBMN6OoCfqlSjSQSJwfTNyxPOIEz0bJ6fH27XXcShflK2Ne8C0DgA/oidM1ODezQFCdaUF43E7ziInNbYcZc@wZHEmFgvQ8@QsNMNWANWDObYHZoaySnMQzz/Zk0LYIwNzsgpGWCTKvlxewpCaXmVS3/yS7Wf11WybjbKrqOxyPJ4OIqS8K2AOeNfkygZCtrm1wdLczK7SabZiZZmj9EDjHqatWfxUr3sc22hYdG/pmgZNyuwyw0vRKFuETRMYFydVm8e1SBobkQ8wFLsxhOFwTotkMdLPkT0p1lWweFnayreW5Wsa7WRZErwsa5TpbBl@I5ZEYboUmLqJTaZhDNMxZbysLCIPaSH1CIOsQICvs/gshEUMfPWMEy2RZReUKY0GmhltNCK2onXwLfcDqwVDPqrLtgDDD8YmeSR1JHRMRgryoP40GdFW8XIxGnGEUWcKIdrugGC0RxihHAMBr2S2o5hUKl8xcJ0M38nszxAm2BN@aFa89OcrcbQktOIdGfuDi@xiwqgTxzGwe/E5wSCeZ0M9Np0T57HNnDi03TcviXsZfU7c1aA/rwQgGB6IEddJ58ToxuG8BNwm0jiifuEj4IWfwPV6JDq/6aFfTba4z6gV0f/UGijCQtPeoY8FQbkUHOhr69CWAkzbUtGg/zQi70I7pIwMo7679R5bRcecJNstVZ1G72ISiOhyKNmsZ8NSqwdYv5MyhWjch9CHsc2Nmj6Ek/mQQgnnIAmxE@J9dwXU9lAjC07jHadPomkIvQ3Tu3ECw3wEHmPHsNj4LvACWvXyYjxmntPlxuhKs4xD4bjojs0vTdg/ewjarYQU9RP0t80@8a3ZJ3z5Y5/8SVlX2MVkOeoxn78EAeM6uh38J2Xklnoyt@g31djPNYpy/QD7op0aXzbcPsVkth4aIYE8nnKrQugx4IlCAnH5EX2DfKHmE7fn56Uejz/LFZaQvDRc4o17Ay2u@wofQMsajQaapG00yBZho4ErS41GkOdAAy8OeP5BV3Q2HpcELbVhUGwkmJCD8WAiUTvZ3NtLqHowzm2kV4K2Y1hKA02KBeO4O1wJksBqIExP0cxKUJzVk21GqYMP51Hz5QEV/HomBMRz2dMpk7Gt2a9n1/JXyXhClYypzMb2L5@Q2zHlhlf9H8vJ4obk3Iw2ydYZGo@zFBUFDbf@Ll5ojkZBJmxR4JK@KALP16aVPhstgPAi0aOBYaKt0ZQGvTa@wmi1L@jaxgnOmLIRvR2XehDBmFM59wWP6B1RjOyktRWhZ9HyUDI4tpEpCpYUNfXxu6ugcdMi4wFt0l6OKG/cXZu0cRlzqqhjwWKYWPmLIJrTgQY4Mkz49UzqgNszqgNuNKuDQa6oAzfa1MEUHeEQ5nXARQZ24AnsHRzb8@zLQ7U/wIUbv9EGocmNi4VDPtaERn2KnJR@nKIIkdTQMHJE4I3GgqUgVN0mYz7TBn0Qfp5Nn2g9MCtkyQI1FtOnOsxDOtdKUDT@O2gknyKGotkWpYG08SALciWE0kqlOkw@fbzjihhUn6fCDL7qiYigJnEv/Xi88tkEqkxML5AiMHnghRkn4KtM/ncxknIfLXkqyLjF/FBccZtTbjxs@2DB/RhcRS0aeGQm9f@beZK/Sf4rnSr9fz8pmpn6/D1PZR6ZwnzzbOV3OC34bwr9f1Pof4JC/zvT5h9QyadRzvb4KXX9q2r4t6tfJPNGMGxY3Rtcesv8FD3sd6QIrH6THuCW@kJ6TBf4@vjsosn4h/WfOEoHfpM6befPd4xarXbal6zjF7VurVc7RvNLG@n92PnVysbW7caLjXZta6v7srt5oLwp1Fb2zVfvCu9fdD5/UkB73z18@eGzZrZ6gXfH5u25cnSbVQp2bTD4tLc7cnY3zvqbJ7n3q7fpbS3X2VA@bWn21uvTd69OX@ROYrefXh69/NxP9@2jTlou9rO7r/NvN0fneiB3o561d/bVw/5Je/ss09/fUt/vxDbT@yfFN1J6f/v2Q3bzNpZLp/bMV4cvjs@umtsftOO9/fftzU@GnP90fWvupdrFzubV8dvAYfaNtPvp8LC7nSm@2E3dbnXMdjqzq1m5q3fHRxtn73d7r@Tt/k7urPjuanSU7715c@McxLor5/nBa3slptfevMm80l/c3GwfB5qycWpllXPjjWTe3h4Zxf6q8upgt9t/Y0l66jD3NnbSP73d2t7QPq0Os2fvz9/crpy8H7x@8/LDYVo9OWluy3mz2c6cXJ2uBFr97F7s5mz7rCC/aJ@/6d/s7ebeb6Ve95SDWvtIu37R3f1gnBzt79Wy9kCX9jdvtPcvelevr7c29zTj6FrTayupnHbafn94GDh7qTa3lN139svaVe99KrdxvfI@1jZfnF597l2/3Dg5OyxkhkejtLFpHzd3O8Ot43ymkGppn44/d4zX0tmbWP7m6mVGfV/77ASyn0e54r72XunrL2Ot7ofhJy0VO5OkzQ97n9@/P9m9sZo1/ezT253jK@t1Wz@0D9PHL1@9bmrXBefK/KCfnEit9Avl@nUsLQeGZ7s2tJFyKudWT/v7b8zhlvHpeO@Dnf8cuzm/zipb18dva5@O081b3XynW/tqfzPdPpRrbw1nezB80SrenF3vavufDu33gdfbUi63Y3Tsjc7bleK71ItY5/rFuw3pZJg@0I87K3nr4O2bc1Xd7r07@3zcyu28NQt9R@@@@XzW345t7w97n5VCuqmdvL/WA2e5k@OjzK3@Su07O7vHr/POYXr/7VF7dyTV3ijSrb66OcptDa189nzrnfX@elc3U@/VT4OjtHITa783nZU3arPTequ2@q8CJy97ZwdHb2/3cnnrRV9XN44K6YP93c2Dbnvl1Wjv9WB7v3nVfrH3TnlnnuavM9sb5/mtdydZ5/T6lVNs3fSzR4XYqdZ3umexwMtBb7B6dG59ejv8sFLrN5XssfbeGK1K/c2XZmb4trZ9@Ll7fWQaB9JOZpQ62zeutfTn09vPu3a@NooVhmdO33BOpWFOehPI3n42nZfmyzcnhxsvDz@8lFdU9Vy@OnnbTmfPCim1Z2X38vkX0vZOp/@pX1Skz1uvs3K234vZ@9ep9mb77O35tXbVf9W/agUKRbu1sfdhIBvbzYyUfr/R2c4p@xv7p5Jy1n11srJ1kD561z46@zQ8bW@@G5y9PVTT21cvi/vdlXfHb4uvVj@c2qfyufHulXUQGBayhi3li7nb7EmxcNizTrLnV0Xnw6ur/IZ23pRe7mX6yo5qvSuMCtfm595t9/ZESTe7L7Y@ycedbZCkZ0dpOTe4PhieBLJvT/s3q@ZG7P1169U7XdIK5@pq6vTTVfG613t1u9VaOa99/iTnXlwpxZOdVFPbyb2IHW@@Obrqbp1/Lqy00xv7b@V3w@2e8z7wZlfduiqeXx8OR9KbnZNRv5bWtdzNyXnu5tTYODnfPSn0XjetTnP3qgeyoT86u7od3Owqq73hbeFV7@qtnN5/V9jU7ZWjdOClstdvH5@@eleLdTJK0bk5fH9gnhfOh7nXBeO8aBwW1Fe1zovhm8POdnrVVM9Ph2fbvdTGptovgEw50s6szcM3ux/OX5rpQEbPb3zeNHKrn2I3w/f589RRbH/wvnWa6Z9b1u471dp5d3P07tVJbS@21xy9OLqWD99v504ONjftl7EdNa@MdrO3dm0zq3WMgN3fGB4MLbOY/XC934WRwGgX2y9Os@e6Xat1bvcKJ9u12gu7ufdSHg5fdFZhjMDP9vlboxL4DTetF@BW9fhD5vY7An272zSGIC/55b8A3eoK0K2uAL/HRUek@fHj36SWA6f@@wz0JmG@wDNogrLG2gYqD0m259m/xddfxFnfgOQqulqGSU9EK@5ttHHCp8EvrVfh9UJ6D6IyNDVDxTcL4VsOcE5qjV9Zlgwc6qw/wvmmo/T5LQsVXw4kzNXSixH4O5jIXGZgodVi7tsik2SM1Xt35EdQIEy9myDru12WSLQ6mty1waG1yfUxcOJZh8ccNFXGxQ/MQtpvyFI6J46m0hvesHCn@E6jgxdMM/hrF9wZhwzKxIjsl@AiFdkwUfCNcrZ6o2gjeo@G0k4G@InPJ52C9Ifh8e7JMDIZOnU2FNQNxZo6AGryhO5Oa2r5OZqWeb6cElusqAw1ZKupOvi@4ga/L9HgObpn3szJs4d061ds0HLFCDUbMrYbF9eXhuibSoUUo2PmLbp3whGgaogqqnvacHnZJJR07opxjw/zsvkwbrXf/V2hnsDdVpUJvAbQagC0og3pmT3772w65OgBlQN8s3773d5pQ7xshR8xnLgU9cCJSx@Vy67PLPMa@MovSj57LBNPGEDxcdmR26qGqt4YnJeDdO4Rj0dCa@MMe3zaMglcQycNEJtJp1EuVur8BGGaju65BPfSPOOc8MxXqmdjgi6IAxUeDzwxHT@gyUFm64uIO5aiEACd5nSvhkwd9vsd894DLdPUZP0aXWV@VBbmC1bL11j0GglfPXApy6uLOD9JcwSsNyT1jsGOCxq0vGYhAHEg1m3mMx27M523xzS8hb2scX0M8/BmXZpmtCLj6GX3yA2vW9TNicNPZXWIK4kdPFlrWCOeES7PRMplAMFzOiQTFN09reqrdWVMDURHh3p8pQC@LbtBaGJAGZczzh4vLc9qkdiBTgDNLyo/DIRQF16x6jyrh2Uh0Dvqr8xE0jFx3CNE4EwtM8cwgQgdwXEwjBGP8NOpM1ThJ708LmKcThfpOvyzdb@nxA/uYodScNkTRUgUuzHO0KcK5xUaQate18GsxqxHDYUnuLEJVeJFpsIMH8OZGotNtJMP@YWKdJNYjKgdmRMLYsirkSC9oD3B0Jk4aA1@FJd1@AkuTuvAFInWIKMvX7wOA16PG4/ca5jAEt7b0ZHBOWfyviwIWnb9bif03BQzJoonVe9nz9LTDVSYgBu3pjpUtAgIzAa@RMZkECSOLJkmdxCEd3wJgrGxqexCXi0uRiDVBcGlCnX2jEWktbXIaiJCQd8VolGvM4rkGV9yX2IQ0tUqi2SWI1k38QomBpTZSQQr8xFkOIKV5YjkIsgIBFIOMHAVg5B8xwqcaycRF3yIPbz1SRh8Fc2c3JczMam@tlbAM56@wKnEmflFX87GMpCYo16ITcZwtDzCF16frBEgz2Z844gPxUosCyh41rHJiHGuUxFepv48V@pzB6ffmfLi3tNwBx9Kjm/EVKyLAtYXOZUfSjcZuE3HEoH4VjKT3k02DuMsvYxsDjoCdUnIrafgpak4fzedGLSAfuWpUdF3OYIgUAwQEVw8apxdPTbWNb99sEPgDi3w8TrHmRRnBZiGgEQBiVGAxCBCiAZqt9Hqmx4cDMWFKD/xzQcwyuQAd5zx/gC0E6r9bk4kxjj5cIcb8Il3g9EYwukbgQSN/b0NfLzdPsYTs3sHL6AJF7AecTb@dau5yDF6VdyUdf6@EtVRoQgg2/iERtSVN9Vk/hjo5i@wucgF/DR2npBqhxCMJxbaIfGF6jRUQ2DjpHT5SHGIjvT6LA@gEC3DPIPdKkzWkBwj/trfAn/LFl16o9REKnB4CUUBkUJIs9Pj2sHJzuHxa6LcUaO2f7RbQ8wwwWzJVpvRe2Cwg@i6ovFB1aNnAIffLr54G@skN92XlvBXkiMsf6EgJx4ANiimQaHTJcL6cqafgefB8xKQRPGgQalotBVzDm48u@qBicrYcxDyVuSlFkOhKNO8kZAGvNmR0JWjVZR0REtDsfWwA4xN78WRdS5PUi6@DZhl0ksFqeeiHtUlfrH4W9SyGXq1MvKRPTBxd1hpB/3kl1stxSa7B2PqA0pF61AmQrL4CAUh82s/lh/8boo39goc9GZJGnTTnt47VnMnlUXQHjntfpKO61OQOBZXR7pz1UpSi0TO/E3PE6qjOqkyPpQZz@2K53YFuXGBy66mFTK1fnE1oYjNI4/qkueK68auZsbVE@8oObVcBzq93UNzRLQWwqUONRg2E5niMEYTsu6Z22TP3F487onzlbvHlTJB2EmNTAw44/FTTJjbbSBbZGZtg26u0OxrYGH7c4@u3KKHRkp@0cmdYhA8cUoD1GkXzhWfeIfqQc5ATCAN6bbMhciuToOKhy8iELKEW56oT9egW5hiVUDVQVqML6eJupIqadhiougLRLEqRmGr7XZyghwPZlZ7@kIXAmEov3A4vpXAr/HxjAropLdSVgg1cshYZ6UIrqsmEpAgytc1SKcBcYt1oOKpzvxqFGarISrn6mQqvwGDok64JS4KEPQLzHsg1M28PLfevnq4l@EwcdRXsXRZ3KBwb/SeHbGslM36rv8enh@wfH58OxjtmbGVTHp85Rgtm7F8MfCT1snG6wmcH7HjiAZFtkKewak76IKKpkEn5o@2ikM/lo1Pi4f8MSp7ytUyn8HaQhyLocFmfXzffVPB97rjfq3DpKGUDCyAUKQ1YPHCTHfwBsDuQLZk3VH4HUsU5GJnFzOkhKjDKhbUC190j8fGUOLj695hWLAUvgAMIW2jRYckEQelg5Ye9Ok0UhwVhhvFQjMAqiMu@i@QzBHswEVDlTOBG@gKh6rLG5yEQiRQj8ZFFk5GGpaRenzpRbgypK6c7qeplKf7Eg1p7rt3sQBEXsEqRGPuDiwIAs8MMzQfXxYvIHO7pAc8Fv3zlgZnBxk@OXXn4QINH2NmZ/5qfc5iDHFXyz8GDcUhJkJFdapH3TtwJAHcK1Atdx2CA9FjWKfhiXDx2ShSEOYvbZWvhTOSEaRF0ChFQ4qFXIendISVO4pe8N4@Tvxcgd4XFScDRuLCnHc9UkAgy0c5hLgbOQ2B/ZNDDP04oBS8oy6nxucPhojDu@@G4ps4xJ2Fozsq5gWIgM9rSe3i5ed30ubXQvRRypRfSZsuKUVFfX15PhivsgDD2vnAoFAkj9xKuWBnR@N7by4glZ4WpB4r/ERuTy28yG4GaIISTyy6R4h7sVY3Dykk7hs3Ct@kEsdqhJrpax@uJEEjCkYgnqV@L5YqBA1cqcBL1/Sl4Dqzm8aVJBQjLv3OihwB5TmWM@51YFege8uc43u98yrKOdmtqltNakF6A7immjQ0TtZVdAt/XRPSbGVXfZV1bxlPVFYkcus5a99BB0dHM265/QUcUILi5nLwu3acfdfGzRAR4h@jXGrMk3@Td519HfL7yrhHevXzykqXZj0P76ti7xBFu5/fMR3iTbudHF8BTUOAhOCGXnYP1/NUCwtCnQGlZyJdJiqWnT12dlF0OiCv6ag@WrDdz7iYxhxDWCrsB46HhqDPijUB7IJ9ITmPBYh6sB0VauqD9XGRkMwTndTlDoyIxcR4VplYDR5foH6QEf1YhOz0XVF@ND3JlNlSjDCOD5PzcbhJxHA/7v9lf0FGDxYEyUF7RGKs8/aMuEmE@992Z3Ssu5lCcwO9y8zAzyehiAn9LZd29YCIOdYXvNkBnw/4dQOhaLvKIC5sgQIPc2N@NTrOIPcH4ccWRj7xDT68mgcpyQKIPxmZmvALJF7CjG9aZPomMbPFpNYhipq8TSbLTQ1JCyEedl6NZ@YFIktlErgNyJ0xaaZWE@gYXXKm1bgyN/5BqizaHqd5qt/6Bzb8MlYetyzH8ywTLwe7px0Ihdo3NYXf3JH2G7XDPc@0Fes5jllKpRTbwCA7aVjd1K16raY4YOBEmK1KKAPs52ikisc0ts9gKEODU06SnSj8sALqvaiWfaTppDKIfsREaAFLB@BOBzRevaXgC1CcWzw/IBDYSX9hIVq2QQ83dDYyjOa49LK4mcMLEKey21D4LhBm0ExCAVIt2bGVkZLChKmmBj99Ge1Ip2BKnsIapg51ZR9Sn0CXUJJX8o0c2PIVjG5OT@VKZugCCVw7ohgHXxlOp0dwDcHBc5GsaUDbeOdTxSSBTEkaujZiOpoA6Mr47npGbzGGrJDzbqGadOJWbOrQkQeF5hEr6WKehL0tRjhKh@N3MglxuWiAv@62hPc7bAPZxVLobColnzjTMnUmg3fMyUMUfJ4/GdZC41xfP6fhHfFIpXxpDf0p5z7mnfEg@19A9odOfqRSuDxqavKIBW9lsuDNNldW0/kSzrXUrk5siL0Fjej4NHZlaOJLY/FgAI7jblpNuVE0lsVmfKvaAwA8cQZQpUDItORuX3YBI9kSw2x8Nrpofj1xo38cZRjaZEgH702w8Ywab6YxJo2x0Q0uMaogMUWwGBeUKEgt@FnHI8@GYbISONpKc9ClwQDvZbkp8HaUHG9iAjlajTSj6/AswROKjkVahn6Mnb/i2a/C80SGyi6gm9eZu0ERLAeoFtD1K7z0ZTc9jhwI5tvRgQGb72rAiLDMGmIyylcJABrHsAiHs/m6J22euyBtY@8QV20oQ3642I3BKprC2OODZ0qWme9MCYgEtDeFjEkmsFIpd2UkXMPX/7qejTCPpVWjCHePl4j4qLfskcM9v9Dhp0/WyCYYIyOeRM5o2T1VL5XZvQuIZ0BQw8GTJYmwe3IANUwL92bGJ1KA9EF3FvYYWl8Bsl@BpIZDNsNxyVcNfsC7zle7hAoyHS3V3T0sCK@kyy41@NvCvfYfb2Y94625QBVfpHeP3zGhTgdbfCOGdknEBtNEWXHwEjxC3MFxiSE@wvmBAia5Qawm0qJp3FtQ5QXla64gLFDnTNCQEmdD1sXVdz59irOR8KKl@gA3Rp2OjypS2bNereiD/h1ORuI8ycCMI/A9U0DalwP4K2Z0Fs/c690wSpBYR0EeIEGBQRduOC5t3KXjTLovU84teh0YF/GgR8zy/tyzWJc64itdwFSE/ut8mCh91w7GeX64ZUAOyXVk6vFxbpyIXqmHI@M6MoyPQHQwvI9UFbMOdIvFefKOfFFko0Ts0wgBg@uwDRn3HRtIu4hrgYw1hhWYIDVGFVzD4/a/UOHl3YIMyCB8iQFgIoGAMENlrrJL8URmEH3DWAzjYVI3GT8wSzjLdtPPxGPrEX6e3o//fmwkj@jQGMYbo6h7LgVSNEbLRALveMr9THWpeL9FfWfKO1XfGXp49X2AHl59Z@n5k@rrrRi/o4rAEEMPnOPglH0dZtQA7QXydYp1hoHp8Qi19X469cDElw1NpaY3SMymNkzTsNHW@fwS8DznFILifeGQ5zrPowRumCCn@PKRVEhD18O3AtgB3sUtA/XFCLnxtY58/AJ9UuNr22KMpgDEXKQVfc@bmPJDBlExlPiDXJHo1Q@z4jKVqxOgtl3T@eIK82VV9gpOFeVzMEaJvdpHGff6cPiqTscXoTRuEiRUlM1LMkC9A9NNJ8Gw@UkE1YV8nEyFVGdzU7mNiKnF6UpXEyKxE9zjs6Sx1h307TU1SDoDu/r0CW8e6633DmMug/PGoJXecMwdpWEqtteh1bZNfhCbHYnVKbz2BCq807OMQbfH0FAU6oAIy4@UdwzU7lG7BK0e3@U5QFs1JfdYXGRcfW/9OMXOTAaTfLo/jz339RHbRMW/OcK1ZL4WEPENE@KE1cKCqzstjJe0F0jSe8B1vtDHVxzG2VOb@QqwhfwARXiNK3GQ/TGx05yM3UEsIXkaSFB2HLSsj5q1yquA1R8nM3EbZpwQNQDXxhcpKwse6PzCcjb2lZZK5y/uPrDKvNKm5xaSrqFOF7Kp4FJf@pHC8VXE6bUbKA7mjqXZUv4e2s/Lle9ew7z/K6wJmbpcGSc4BSa5eDgalB28mtdHA@RoWYNzKszAAeWBYeHccBSfi/kW1@Ood8m3MPeiqTLCxZKiOD2Yz97gQaO5qWnHrSdDU9HVAUQEJSDViu@d4X4ZvtgNU7@m6aiXmE@AbVLl0O4sL4bRwl1mN/EsJSyjpShtG1VWGXmFyhnB6w2iu7q7hG1V7uIMEWbqruh1i0Pr0TRb7Kktfitj8wiLYimfBqrFJ9tYmiS0JZ37AVbY7Cmta4LFlxuNsSdUPQFk052E0WH2p4Fs4ZKDYbFY2A4IGc9HmmNxEmdajxICqjwBTJxXmVVCfMCofqIpyCm2ctfrcKnGlXl0WAffxxG2xdswxJoR0ta/9oOrJkkG8spbkIHhWRM3dFWb8Pim33HWGWgoiw0ziXEoCScr6/ehYtlcrHAjhhPV9HkmgLhgnYz1YRTHUCwPQ4SGcTESc0nzdfDiDDRm9QBwgkP/v@0923IbyXXPwle0htrFgLhTlEQRHC4lkdplIokKRXntgrhYXAbkSAAGxgxEYCluxbmnkkqV440dO7ZTudhJJa9Jyo6rkoe8r//BX@A/cM6lu6dnMENS2vW6klq5vMR0nz59O919Tve5aBnLGF89aDCUsXGLPe@QUVB0fwHZdH9uI70FCqaPuhYTV4oQWKZWKFEli2jpKF7EOvJHZRMzgy0iBjgEK1x2/pwvaP4EMkAj3Htgg0Hzd7xh7LbxspKaLqVPWOnUSyRk2RXYB4bTQdgeuf40GMx/3YSQu0LxOiXvDElz@vya/Iyz4yiGsXRWxWAAYre6R@puqJuAgjps3isP1jHHOpBbDU7c0JfnrBhIM5igpEL04DORfYB5D2QeHo5KJyCRgy4T8KYH1QRCsvEqsdoAbJ1kLjYKK1ROKdi1u@GUNtFjH5UrUKd0ivdBqOMxQRMxmhLcsLEviNwfuxOuDKht7k@FOp@BXiNXn7BBRr42PahUHn2EH/dm7BbSPR8kgAdxG6hQ5fDINcrA9gsNB3C6O4J2q@Ot48o7Cjzc@HULo3FiDVQt/EXcHtvARRW@cW38Cod3vlgl4k6Uq6FbAVhsxi0Z69nbV6V8X1CCfkL/iVhmddelYJmgpG4/viSQVsXitZwSYL0GKVrYnoOaGhtoYQHrEkCb3uFVB99aWGuD7s5wFk@AQNz2pHsMXYL58pBgwgmNU8/r0bCBDIfX3tqVeSAAPcYxKjADPZoOO@iSpk/jpc006d0DL8kBxI5QF6jmyPTSox3OKwI9P0NVT7o/7hX02uKqSC5B4QcA9T0SnqCyTXR/KQcGvyPNJj06fVt@4lXICg4LfjdlIropkf7oF7JWDpXnei3yrTSSGOvnYCxEl2cJkzC88AoNFacTf/KCX47w2o12/rDt0b03vgWywjIWUjd6@MgfRHn8kqEu56KwJrSe8WA5bocXX/IqagphUxywQQ8bTkUDzG94jUhpWWsj15i2YAvr8g1UVWahZhSX5ZdL3tg18ag3V75DZNugmmm6JcfaMZcCz7W8ymS7tsmgL7mrGG1ISEkRCK1ajtfv8kpS1VEmNATFjWcZhxpfdBRYQ5o7lc2UMxT/uZ1q@CStuKPNmlqNTB@Ow9QR1aGVhLuGqu6yMm9gfbLY8FPkXEcHcHizcaMdg69TG2Im9bvI0mrGGl5XEvK34B43kSW9cmX@OqNDY6HVxKM7eYuoWS4Dkju0MuAK00ZCylMbY5@XfoqpilTy5HAHcLwLDKYgzTfg07wMD8KCfq6XCzQIK0FItGOc9GXefYC@09ZdexD40pUZHaxcKKD3wtd7iVErkKuX664z7WNT8KUfykQGKovWKVf7essh1Vx@8OeRInDSO5wiDl7/BUNbUDnUZ6sVgCKTFfnCLws21Z04opdq1H15R8Y9EMstWa3sg3JhhJ2gB2/DnQ1JVe9O3CP4s@9hi3pBHvkl/fJdyW3zZeLjvd1HBzv7rf2dr@zsP9mhkqTIrw2Kp@Mq3ZQFJ@jceyTx5oOYQ5zc@xMPznE8cSjOEkrgT7p@GIr7IO66II6/aEPJ9tTNZb65rzzIznsauJN1Ln/AzDwZ35OmceChidAUVZWgfycsgPPzsB0UmPjhDCSHVKj1OkBPBhwXKod7JmzmnIP7J66kjk8RoglCWjbgkeL3wxPkAKU0EX9jhpNm0IPV7Fakjq2CxiuHyF@CdoiADADko9btvEJRys21CgPvAs@JbCS2lWMPg@x9ryYec7XbVK3Y5n4hD9ke@KOjnPSeYLSAODc4tEoYA31dDTEZBUEVqLeAngJxpLlH3KEqygfVeqVW/fxcGkSP2L8hbwVvYJL/hnbei3b6qfGT0sz2VQwAg8c5S9jQxcImpVrQpUdrihvUJSpakRW9mTl5tjW5RH/9N2xBnmFALlu3@sUYjX@@9tyXNrP@zD4WvngznFQCjlnlKPJNVTE9@/wMdv6vWI28nrnIRVYUX5pOpJtOyIBqr2M8kV/Ok/Yxch67e3xhj1dN@vonUNrdMpxRgidTu1ZM0VZHsIkrzUfxaKQm8uWU6GMa9DG18l@bOnx2X1NsAaLupqsdv0avDeOIWEdrr6UJrwP1XKDibmrrn8Xar@o11fZRpX0yR94zukjDNSebG1eRpt3m1SsRUwNnSxfW8SXylxrm2rxFOZU3LuOUMro8O9SdGZdMqL/zpWBKaR3kLZQxsji8VjzEnKRW0yZRwtUaMYV4KUcVFK6zxfFLqK1HIxhdlpITMfMSX7bVXsaxwUBUdDag7UEhOUcxlNFlbBbK@NSouciqTC60BZsQ/QL//8XaSpMgG3h8aWT1GzSy@tJq5EurkS@tRs6zGlm6Wp0Gk2rHG1WBNRuI8glw/7klWFDbe@L99@4ciIP3dsT9p/d@W3xt76l4/84jSNkTj5/efbB7T8D/dx492RFUQP/7ijtBlXsBU7/tdl26nV@p1VYFYV4IUL4qnrSH4j2/674E4tkI2sOtY/6ojNxwk0vtvHQnc5@fg8aozBJKqwm6K@K3JnXjhBbXHaDkIb4jKl@e2Eby5hnwzRLZXlA4dG3AzW97xIOQHhc9K2mjDYD3IRXQtPlJlnSn8WmdmJZeRciB0/9eewSBKXz4RNx5tI2RPrd3D3b3Hj0R9/f24fPx19DNjtjeRbcxd59iFgE@3Nvevb977w4lcANqFYF3a2Swfl4TKghOo9J90Z9ieLABSoXyK@bVeymXG/nKKiIQ@ekoct/TA5LCd3d2dtogF@32tTv7734FuRr368KyMMil4VBdWiBcq6HRCNQmo2g32Jk6spblOm9Iw7m4htmNHN0B0e@SUMgL9E7sucK6h9eI@CBNcbOZYVOooaKrgBtRKUewjqAIDPl8aYNQbkJtdHugasOL1b76wKJb0jErypFLyktrQEgxOOPuqMthdFUC0D1rdVO14YQB8EJIJjAA3sFgQth@4e7iJYm4ISGmIQr@kHCTE54Px/dPkGtEA1eZcJcDgazJNvG80ZRigKO2N@J5jJk18e5AMVKoSEDw6CRnMFBXrqQSB/y/fGPDV1mAtGAX7MPKVkJF9OwG1AB7@3G7HwbCdgp4GwwiiDvyWFPraNAGcY/uhSdosPQS1Qio2jUH/20qR/WK4aRAnEqE6cxFvB263LY8@N3LloOSdxdqRL096jQqTMn4Txc24O5CA94EDSAqm/sFuhUah8TYEhq/L0nZDnygSBD5xMfxqEZ@b9p1YwWkrGM/9z76qCAHuRQVMVR8qHVaww5DPeBDyAn6oCI3FyDEkKbkMb5G8Rza8R5Eb8NDVIaYYAM/VIMrazOFB1Wj1MSRlSI/n1Frp03GcBfWShTPusF6@xprn1H0/B2wWR49k3RQTNbSXID@nFGJAT07TdDNS1@gYtE8pJZwcIdctHd8LIJq84M1Z3P77rPyxx@WDqvVI94W2j1@vGClRH5mIZEclofWnSRtQLXSJNJcMO1gaaXPyLslrnKFDBiXYw@Y761WQ@fxtepi@ojiZcXTKfHVK4dLlcnehEgII8lEu1tJNFWVJSpzKAoSQbR3QmPRs65KKRFOvV9vYVx7nIUGjMgI9xFSrzHDqpF@jeHtGh/0YGfJST6Np1vjL6hY5JKi6J9tzkf1A/uuU9wsVBUULSY9nLbaoksKc70ge3WG00vn1QK67fPRwf59eXRr57aOj4fXwrZ9LrbXalu5mI2LjyUD1@XRfnwOWj7c3ggt9L2UjZgPyUVsmtI1cZauLSmav6DGDxfmjtYeoMGzFyOqaqRGbdPRAD3E2XwpDk2jAgUTTcQQPTnY3tnfF9YO3rKtQ1nY99qjLtmX4jaIuK8qT0dsh0ybXUUzTTpMkGaeVMoZm5fGqz1vMacOXsZWIXmQkhwPvVnoqL0gmcykdQSfLMRCoOE1b4hq5OKtO1V7UNCUiM@aqAklokkzOphL7eYSHz7sZJ82mWjcSswbBy@8sWZm3Jl01kVX1ZO5iUgxwngctI/w5Tt9/t5n/nhd1cMMlvv1KXUYlfC76C9fPIGKx/hSXInP4DnToqaUdFaISpfU2JFZXpzD/uwEpWOxn0le2NjWJXMsm8b88TUjkh3xp1v4zj@Xmd2hvO9UWzylbJgTWogOPTt@BAGTCWKw2DKpAoofnskjjEZDn5OOZsjNtXaNWtNUraRoZhJ3IxvoLeDgb9xMbg/JqmC3Pbeq8udTFZ8SsZqMuFuLNahMwHzzxo3rF@FO9kIVL39W3HyGJPfPcDh@2TZQBvOAVIWAcncflVR@RADnDJ0DUmDPVgsmURBYnZQzJdZ3OozM9kFbTiZoiweN2Xt6UML7omStBTFLtC0dO59IJnYCWeiDsYR1R3nVLIz@2fnV3aWgbhfUd/X16@PFhkB4H372Kw6Tue@PcasERnzSYq@oIJKvB6gVF2IJDj6oPf0aMTC3VBzLJseb2@IXbrSR5hq3Qv8F6vWryJkytpmFz1CVYXt8@govuF7RlSnnoU2ALOuVxNZz1lHhyJpbPZ@UCPo6lOUWtzKeBtv8y5YZfHMd1QcpjwGMB0xHD2D@7bwAuWcdbxVUqMl8kdOAP9FJZU4CWg1R9tDpy5yOdgneeDDX6VVO77kYeE6nbkgsJ20d8TK/KSGTETLzlgSmu1qvP2/RsOvsdzgb2Bid9JZsDMiWA1@nXuVU1KlSSU1ZdholHXISSFI6aUlC4cHkhSYtBa77okWTLKPNAcJ8SYy8wWFF6k@9Y0vZsSBNOEKeSCjvjno5mhSKeapRqSNhC13LShJqbnmHFVKglBsQymTRxPJC2vKiAiYwpBuhL5mouBg1AP8rGyGbahIv1tzceo4UPnGD7tQVOzOU8VVsREWV5BhkSew82hZ798X@3uOdOGpscQt5FCqlFPYoFLNsGHVHLdkSTLg/DY9bnKg@k7knLucqFPytgUb@xADiz2SuqoBQHOKyFKeveq9EEw7vsZ4Uu1c4lJOueqz7UOn601F4@mr2iqZ3BpxeBUjgHXFWwUuCdxaGRa5EyWErcqC3OAwLiXxlS7lViGqhFKplJn1z@NLiOrHmC2cSW07vnzB1sDJpk44CcsI2iTuBjyzPuoxvCcPRPY4CbtJbtiNsO9kwPJQqlYXkorilAze6ZsTdeGWXrKSYVcntqBKmMI2nEmAc0ai2guj54pX3SlUWHSp49K8lpR092ui7WU6jccTQsovB1A6NbH6VMPrcy8V/LSw4OYMiHm9Uvm7wgsAg79Fu7jCNx8CIvhfA9OagwHgBLcDRKogB8jJZAKTyixhb6a2Mll5KkfQWR@txsTkZtUToUoqk1xI1Oj4V0VpPzEbXB@6MA5LgjxYIgsb5mjpzQDYLFWctVpEsKEmRxJkW12nzn0JKHWqbZgigx0P1s37IpjcibxY7Fz4@ImYLZOeNAcE9iNyp4LFmpteT6eaRJDaN4kkIo1EJYMCZOKkungv2JBJLOkFLLV5WZLQlo4EjryWPRthyDg1QIqEM0HIclFdNBAugCEJcHJ4sBiivxDhoMR3UIH6CN7Em2mqsRg1aTAc11scC1nIa1jhoMQm6sK/RRhkfe83QLtvnT14hg4810RlVuTO3Ow35pFFOK2ANhbA8TEZLQve8Iy98R0SMFv2qQHuQaFfXpEdslQYC/o1bmvWhAorVNpsgq40Q4m5h8FJeSsV8HWWybxFjrpnHGDyHuMb3cQO0SRDmNAj2wCQbopgMKdCoU0yxYubQcKlZKBpkjCQssXQKn2fI/TaXTlnc4cjvVskqnFncrEZsF4U@qWQpH21sqLGohH7LE6n/GrLxhMMfiziOSpR0zr8YjmmoU/GKozTwu3zZWUJcDSWsNSEdBXB62EngwNeUxb6ogoDm8OJ24IPKIg5sQlGc1ykThxKqFnEsXxqHEtgWcZQv3w6Sp9L68talcbAgmIajemkcSIGLY2otnQKCM/6vlUZqsfFAsyiZ2i514qShcbZjX51kX5SoKtBekDDE4GeJr7R2SMbcpPWBIQZdajxQ6FgcD9vjlbQJRzHt3DW@YK5jycLCemHhllL5BtZYeQ1xLQh7cBBU@gO9vlMWf0JET1ySSIR074FCTKV7PAERCWezIqUPxYAQTmh/q4WqWa0W3Qw93t97d//Ow9ajOw9RiFriPQqvb1BbhtR1apUVjGfPty0t0ilyBKpaYDdytA8bedQ@iWaHThGKHIullk4NuDOLGSisyaH7osrIPRH3IYuC1i/gRMiKvpuB6bGpDXpTt8ovrUIEaZ5gqldSXtuElhAM04lsCcEYyTlD2OLyz0asofJs9CxkwI5osk1mcGi29xkaLhkFhSi/fBZ@xZ10UJekrJ2W8iyiCj7KbuScClUu5A16hMGYwF9Vq@Kucoor7dfagy66vJ32yfHt0Bu0h51euzI@Huf6gSPd09j5foBOLnOoTLV7sLP/pPUY43Tt3CPLCfzXoLyD3Yc7e08PMOcJZF2XyTv7@3v7LVJQ33/6@AA9hiaSLBNQYonAZEIM6NHee3ceGDD8bclGskFIAPIm/JGufErCG7dm9N85mXmUWBWiRUF4yEwFi1JaSYTe0PWnKngb@p9QB3wJLU/wUQbqUlGNySGNjdefMi/ydXpmQFE7JtNxSKCkAW8nRqIQL8Eww@AIC5AvogD4dtKmr/CNMuahIZ8/thNl0UAGi@WkfVc/oNWBy@TJfNS1FTrpyLN06o4AEl@b8tOwX17LnxXQq@SYlIaShfNVODmq5Bw1n15SjqDUSs8ZQYzMa9dGThm8AxRZlNAkRJYpVIBfEBuiWPQKpzkzQJTMgl2V40edCsOGPg4j49dcMeaI3Zqyni/UjwSif0kLHE0j/PnYfJQiApPvU2TM0UTLcz1m9Fd1lm@YbT07Nr1PRXbdFdQeuQcNvhPa7OiFfPZFdCefu2QDWpiRnPF4HqCXb2Oyw1Qh03gQNmCgwslcsAVhEOrhgp4f4n9n0rVrFxVobCC4gglrWZzL7ijRSCgIGYDEPGvTWo/c2LBZglYcZogNE6KeBvGBCbGSBvHShLieBvHpJwzi9e1iUU3epli5cYO1mWPzmVL833TxclnBbihV6Kgw4DOLq9OYkewwDglddNAc1DyzAbnZspvntiyO@tN/B9wmLlmqTJVww89p9jmYf/571jrf0F1ilP6ae2hsUMicyCcvNmHG@8J7ksRVk6QtaRLbT87BZllqFtPLfjeiiA8yiObTn8Zg0snm22rehR4/9cJ1JSpbj6wakgj@YxGB8zoIWlxerS/yNsoGvJi9sq6xqB5ECBjkugmykgRJq/LVuVXWTHz11CrrJkjtMlV@@jNZpzy/UiB@qCFor5WDmQr6X7GFRqr5UCgNNGBItKl5HL36ZoIfxdtgFksDfxxhpyKH57f7599ItjsqmQr/@6nESQVM@lLTnjrw/3BZHNczcXzIKMrlzHHLM0SxmAnx6Y@idvDwJpfZeYvk5394celadunfjUpHx/ymOriZa1DIklugVg@KZ1LRpsbG8wcDoFNSWmMco3rNGUsOz2JpMBbvQF1nS4uzePaKyp6nZl/X2QnkZ8xgKS4J/esRY7TBEQaJNYp@k5UvM1wqc9MxubYCd8jkdplZlwbmMDaax5GmOAbTs5kQOJZjQsYiaplbkMzeWY644Eaq8BO0J@3jURsDtAb@qCIjgHh@dWfoP/fwoJpU0c1F5XmQJQ19FtaaEJAc56D4egcVKqCp0qkI636z3I6A7W53OpwO8A3NkXIVOkaqVtFlHAmCo@kwkDjxxL079QbQAwc5tYhFBDFvDK2kUxhY6UtVn6g6rdrFKqtV1huvkBs6SqK2dSfeOKTKnEVZAF0@EYMKVXgbBqxi4dFA/ZQQsStaR/bngTdybQMeo7h6JSOB/CIUHS7VIMpIjomBo4QaII@mwxiGUznjpBvjcE4lQIsfu1ZawZFzkW7ExMUIIdo6wgvEivRBR65lEIm0IJrEsayUVgs8SoToMZDnMA6xWlqpYUVjzCIXReQZWmuWt/vktoiMWgkHYdPQNAvAEUbo5bhu1qB3kKHb5Vi//NtP/s4qnFarKo1i6nijNsgMFJEkwoqfB/5j9W2gR/lE2iomcP99hJtR99yuN2xjhJrQQA3ElYEZJhAxnwKhodMqfwD7jX9kG75gVIVIWNXqne1tcfDe/t77aA3FlwhEBYniSATrwirysFPJWL5UDEYQSQmLMA9lxQikGrEIpXuFYLrH5F6nbxsaWDBa3/xjGi26y/dR053XZQIhZlvs1AfvCVG31kSrJ0JRMM7DN/@IMftj1p5NR@yPLUmY8HPsAvGrq0h7oV8MkV7fL77/Z1SdtCgBng/vVYZm1VlMP@U25YUs0Wy5fpjZq1g1NAiZiC8com/9mJAFHKRbbYS5K@auqJGkd/uHfyUIBz4@wOwZJUUMT/FCRN9mRPr1gEYuE1/5QnzfYXw9j14BTESdebyLD@GcrEzQaMg2kqsXDN8vvi9bDPBeiG8m59SxHGtuLnUy/tWcWSorpyNrfg38mTP8AxOpNHPNwsgHVSqeT34WLVOzm@w6men7irE6E01L7fAn/5lGfaRjDqsHPYAzWnOqUtdKRpv/4i81/lnuyuwCgvnl337vR1EfZ5k9m2X253vRapot9mKW1fYriS3pq3hkWMVZ5lT8NF5NbOXOHOMzC8FPssZ9Fh/sWdaSB9LXi352wbLPQvJthUQv@NmFSz4L13cUrtTFnuxWxnKfZS5zhT1joSfwL2c0Exbjv5iLcXbezGeu@Wyy@BtCjgwfGo8uTEu1KjmcGrG2G6JOf9EzL/7dTLbG3P3wqi1iXBzgqAAdSk0x2kOo2Ya58k@TMeXPmK@JUuvS2YLqkVFLXdYCokl7EKRU5TifW10rOHQg7qXUsvlmleTOqtWRy0b303EPpQ56vxuS5DGh5z8MHpC@M36D5hK4bRBX2NqG3BM0qcmH9IITLJAPoiOfQ0rUQA/QPRA36O@G7m65zikkb1xJYhn4zBJdoet0FIUyBREpSRTrh6lCBcupqQvhn/QOxNJVh6UrHCzZR/IjG@VcuHl/60d6R9Kj5MexJ1AWL8b5j3IaSMWI3srJY4fk6bJRO7EvLUjFU9URkHl0/7O5WySqy@YlDbAszN/9E33QuQHqsvagP2jySh7/MTgmDkzmCWjsn/yTENiF5WjLyKz5T9XEB7xDZVWOJ9kl6smo5sd/YCFppw8SZzcuFrIkxkwZS@w@Ek@f7OyLvacHj58e4IWM6RhRy@DZgh6L3bwvkwAbvyRYkGUbIOavsDhr5DF5eSWvuFKg7v/597D7jLboWDXLGKZzy/0gVq6uyp0zRjQVlx4hOT4L5fnSAlrHdcveOs6aHCEQoHdHIa7XwIUfEowvJtjhszzbmPzZZNqUumXFjOcSU/95dsu4jMm@TMCjDifAqQucP6f2JWV8MZRBV1ZzfL1z0l7zGD/0Qrn8JNAvmoJiN5vpF74nJyeVPoanmk68ihuge6IAHcNVx0fALIx8utREt9lAeF4XZFt0Xjjtvoh@lbvt0ct2gAoy78xQJdq5/fac/@ay7ojHR0MOxfGm98RC0G1vaV7qlgBZqdN9Ueqf9Boygw2DtcIJJyL3M1Efw0D98sZ9DeGHeM@uszqDF11/QNyu1RnAQWZFVXMPFeRcfcrvsceGMeoSeS69nwpimm1WpBD4aEA58BO4KmVd7M2a88NY8ZkuHtNmCTgi5rlIWSEY81mPg8IGzDh/FlWqqm3OpLN4bUKGrw@oFKIgEc1cwcQswjFnxkrxm/hChWkIOY@loeVP16HSarz5C@bRUYQBNDGGAXftavODZ81nh6PAPVk@LFaPSujoCKE70qyRxpR89vBvHP3By8HYD2JJIzcIWcGlppK6x5IamFZY8UWOVULjBpqlFW68aNBQO9ChTNyi74S2J81USRvnmJ63raYVjTE3rCkbgyPtKSUDmYYPT4apvYno0ECE6bpLKhJfmi6U9f4E/Wkp2DKMOTqAGc3RjBADNcSXioxhKs7ircLXMk6AYWcfuImuqHyYimYiy@jmmZx/s/lXX7v5fVgX6a0nguVNMaE0NnNhw3XlcmGPmJuOMa/Qgupye4Au/6ydEbmnUYqDhcZyVZmmcD3YBRl01pj8rnQ8wS@pI6mFgnXNUfYVc4eXJa8LNaRa0yR6had8RQiyPG8gHEEkpZgri83MYiDp8sZBz2JpxU6MRs6okTMuwtCzjEYeymIYyNN023CITtvacB4Bvjpr9JJYKIL2S4xPxa6Ilqu6zmjPISpQFoYwoUhn3cPU2ptGo41NK4EACXEBQc/tt6eDcD2X3PDqZf2l9ygeSrVH8ZckA94rgMBoC26wUpmtiUy@WOBVukduL@FXM2fVS7VSnf5X4/9bJZWo/l9fTKzFIevxxFop8b9fS@Ihjmy6WFSvreKGnPvVkhjPw2N/tJJbEvrMFnRmoz9CfkF9HvD7cDDyxmM3pDBH4sgd4eM2Bn71fLyxQOdfGFcHfr9wyb/IukIu@Cm29TxoIaKWRFQZz4V1bcuCcR@O/UkoPhp4HfUbY5TfXFVfwTxAN1KB6xIPFAATJJ@5Ud/3YDLfDfdGeC9RRY/Joc@/OwO/Ux2CKO9OyJVjAGseIDy/MpmOquRuyh318FmczBDaL6Bpx1AddK3XArAWdssuIOUFLrqntJ7N@n2LnLe4g94TFxk3vD0SOpLKbo/4jnZwbOG2tiQeARO2zu5WlA8T7aWLRtwVefkYVx5wPGfSGMgbkb5Q4x1jWZJmhoVK0fK9nlz/WRV6gIZSVoHYMrtAJ6IfRvBKlVMWYMWQWAnsIwbpY8YYz4qoRxgi1EXLEtmIohAygdoRfcpKowSqSJ7PXgnYQ@yVsqJ1bZhW5hnr6@jeE@/KnHpB7xQe2knV19YxNgf1BAcUp0k@DdfXMIccVAYCI86xbxqzH0VHtgQAeUIoECLw2BP0yNB5TkqkeFkHhwfSX0Xl4fVEB12iDSjGC95fjdwjipIiTjoeh4LpeQEBYMnq0UfeWA5RKUaqnekRsNq0FiiyihcEU/fGrbVVahDFNVKgPb8bA12pAmZ0LVulxh2Hw4Huxe3wWAzcl@6A/b9xsyn2Cy9KojNbbp943XyzQKQDQxnrKYyCfbvEads79x/cOdjZLoly/QaCs4GqhrWNweXsIuWTAYckIyzCy7fSubnKRG4HpfxWNV@QTd8yh71oNlghgD1rgnLc2M47VEzezDFiEJl6uFeVdLxFHdsNdbVxuWFTphOMWmCpwVUrf2nJQpLGupaQBGObI5QpRIcGfMHGswCUuVfACMjdrYVCGIYSIsq1Nq6Wy3pNrdOvMmys5fIm25lb90AOfyHy@9NRbLfN09ppizxscugtj7e2q3naFypWQxw7@beCfAO5c805vbSnhVMV4m/Ux1bYPHAH/t25mj97qrRWYEAKzfphoSAT8v/z3yD2nUVmAQM7LJwif/2Ro1zCVnhT32EPmnaeb4Oh2EeV0J2F92hzDZ2woQt0/N68QiFJe/fg7O3ZH5l1jO3CKWk3dx3neuEUqpyM0Q5lDJuhewAYCw1M68fSIpHj2bMRusVdRvnrqw8fvAdTvo/@pYKw@cHh8rVqKZ@HI540kByM9CG29x4@xpuESaFCNwr3J/5QjsukrSup4MM@Wg5T60sWdq2KqxB2ziM3lL0P7s4P2keP2kOQmNswBPELnLap9YNh7lGX3xwjx4pPrlU4PXII6nji9hvMCZ0Fzkv7qNAI4c@xWcUNqMJZWSHsIRRy0IFAYtS9EZzW7x08fODkN9oCsTopqyJf7GjiAEIhgrExiQTaGOlgOF2kqpDtNolg4F8xb23G@7JRbW/mG2dnme154Ld77PErHxFwz56WJMVNnMUpbUwiKpiPXQcT@Gh7d@fAKkFZlH0xkWIczWnTYmfEjqqDyQ13CjoC508QxnFW336b0rDINHCclVqtgOohZ4CNfEAAWl5Yk8bZpO30bD2Q7bFXoatzd8Z1EXOyUlmptkfBCbCj1frN2u3rtXf8Cb4b9Nyg@3YAW4jTxpCyXjh/Gw35SZ3syB/03@57A3ywurq6vLbn3f2dr95@cnPb7nZ@C3hI63ng4wP@ZGw2YNI@kdp/sMdOukxd1IgR4Oy2q@P2C7@62qt112pr9Vs999YNd612fa17w71@u3P79u1uf3Wt07t9q33rRrdTRbfRVKQyJOVBi8kfq@1frtosxmxtpXa736/Xb97q3bjdv71Su359tbN2o1dbXe2v1dvXr9/srax1bnfO59qi9uRgg1X7Lp4dyR34rWzmLrewt8vShf8F';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWW_wWWWWwWWW/WW\WWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvw/WWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 6  \=>axfnuen le._e _=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Numun Cr Uu8 gutyIO 0; 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;r=pure;q _=r 0;data D a=D_ a;d(D_ _)=r 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212]!!(l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+k+q?2+(d.D_)?3- 39);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on the version of BMO's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153774) [provided](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167728#comment405456_167728) by Ørjan Johansen:

```hs
import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe
data D a=D a;f(D _)=p 0
p=pure
s _=p 0
g%n=unsafePerformIO$g(error"")`catch`\ErrorCall{}->p n
x=s%2
y=(f.D)%3
main=print(x+y)
```

Test above code [on TIO](https://tio.run/##bY@xasMwFEV3fcXD1GATLBq3Q6lRljhDpgRCoUMgURXJEtiSeJLBJvTb3STNUNoOd7icc4f7wYOeJsEjLEBRHYgU2kFhIZmXL6@QVIC9bbT4Bct5@RMW77uIRsQ/1vN/Vs0j/zanyXTeYYSlsxFdS1eDkD4aZ6s72I0hyo6uN/TNBq4kOV3HNXB2SaWyGg458/BIPPM9ShLgcKtNall/W2wlKofdevPQZBLRYZLkx8thoY/71bUvedueP4uFB0sGFtKSjCxTtM7TJ9JxY5lHY2M2zMb8Cw).
It prints `3` with StrictData and `5` with Strict because Strict activates StrictData as well.

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;k=f 0$f 2 64;r=pure;q _=r 0;data D a=D_ a;d(D_ _)=r 0;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212]!!(l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+k+q?2+(d.D_)?3- 39);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
```

`e=error"#";` is to get rid of parens for Prelude, also it hides the rest of the line from Flaks.
`data B=B{u::Int};` is before `e=error"#";` to fix Fission – see `D` in `Data.Functor.Const`.
`D` → `D_` is for DOBELA in `(d.D_)?3`.
`%` → `?` for Cardinal.
`p` → `r`, `s` → `q` for alphuck.
Some golfing as [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167728#comment405556_167728) by Ørjan.
`h pi,h(0::Real a=>a)` and `do a<-Const[1];pure a` are swapped for DOBELA.

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dZRbb5swFIDf8yscmgdYQgQ06yWOqZYmUyv13k2blqXUARNQwabGrImS/PbsQNepUiiSAR@fz@dqz2gebbc@VchFYTeJ8gbzI4FMjjTbOeojDSNZ8HnkI9PPsh2VQ2tHxfx5xeZUxX/YRayYpEm@Szk11G1B8/i2EIrVAL0a4JLOY/8M/H@n/o45Oq5hhpTPb6gCv/iOFcf6XEfEnMrlR6E41kENM14oxgMWjFhIi0TdFQmrIQ9ryC9ZlsR@lb2RqI3LseriuirSEfPjtM5Fu7ZG4lJwkQqZRXGe3rFcydhXseC7uF2Xe4AvhE8TSE9QY7KuwPeVifqg7N6HwIgq@gptt26cZkIqVMq6XwvuKyG7p4LnCv9b@cYWqnvGJAuE/yYDBSVF0h0vfJaVMb4t3C9zxdLu@XX3O89pyPDK/GFuYtiOcp@hMsg4QJS48EcDvTKEqPESwf7Ic13ikZSlmVqaJhrA03D/s1AQNESvmqEU6TlXbM4k8sgQwanBvDwjrJy2FnuLhhuUUQ7JcFX0@6C7wYwwKYXU9jQcnnBSVA7eMBkKmZ5ft0LEHqFP/Ojx97jUO6VJstqYrkQcz8mktLsuXwNT06amOVlPG@6CWHi5R0lezJSkUAprZkMD4wXI4IjhBEJNGJ@rqJVH4gVRHKEZmT0s8BMJkQU2HXTQw5JkhWT4GZyXyMKV5yNARx4QgQ4fz6hWqt3JBDq2A03YgfukAwIYhzDvwbBhONNmU090m9kdJcYc0mb1@2X2IO3VFL7UaDufEj0QiA7MqgoTe4pLLxDtRCiLO5EO1B2jyau60X5qP584bT3ojjzjZN9E@8cGfl8c3cB60yA5e8Yh0R@Q0XBTGvN1whTKmh6xSCZjrlp5kU6s5oHdWZmeuUlorlrl9TUpWhPTBtet9Xyg/XK1KSR50/gL).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Retina prevents replacing `f 0$f 2 64` with `0\`f\`f 2 64` on that line.

Comment: Aha. Alternate approach: ``x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;q _=r$(d.D)?4;d(D _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;data D a=D a;b1206=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212]!!(l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 39);instance Num();(!)=seq;f=(^ )`` (I also hope this improved the DOBELA fix, assuming the `_` is meant to destroy the dot.)

Answer (score 6):

## 217. Haskell with [HexFloatLiterals](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#hexadecimal-floating-point-literals), 10370 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM7@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WMqUb2lnOm2nL@nMtJVKSqIk2hTJJClbSqc/VNcseqem@6GnprfR073TVd2zg@0FBpjGYh96ML1YYPp10Jjf8PXTorFA/YPac06QFHWx0/lVNXYWGNoigxEnTkScOHHinLixKdu9X/86hBc7NLRRVzMc5ii2w9qWeq1YSbY@Ys9k1c5lsoKAUDWrO@grumOXhBCTGFP1ltqGd@YYV4quflYs8M8wZlpG15L7zOnJDlPslmwqNjMGjjlwmNGZHy3L2FbfuFQTGLOv6l0AcxTLtBSHwlcYO9U1ud9sy1MhuakETQvCbbapaF/6XxzWMvp9WW/bAJln7JVh2QrCtxTbNjD6KmPDLaU1hbQAoLKlGnu1/edTQUXGnkMWZVNThkxu2o4ltxzV0JEmaXa8f3p8OBVDktibk@3tad8Me5kwdLY9aF1NB2XZqWXLmjyNf4XVBo6x60z751itq@gyyySLycx0YJ6tW/JMlFVmKXK7o2pKEiqEJVhP0UzFYujDOobFdiFLWiFdSDdq45jJFsYtjAOn0RaZls06U@XJpIHwhtVTdMhhejpQ8gOnAjJ@QFulBGRrxCJ2z7CAjyw2sJU2uzGsNjCXro2icYjPhp9ZU7aV/AoiyPoIrnTjRgcmcgyo2ubIUZhu6AmKjIArTNprTDNWJoe@tYPdaf88y@xN@60Co7WuOrN1mSmwI8McTfsW2St1bx47Z9O8IWwYbaiNqTCJHcrgRclMEj6bmWwFLahdaMzs0oaMtRVm66ppKg4PBF5RLAqG2ExT9SvewA8toz1oYeNzegqkjQ0W@cEWWhCrykxXTCTRwULEQRwMcnBs9JVgfm2mK1BBtqm01I7a4oylDB1FtyHLdpKpUIgbVdNYW9Egwhh7K85sA6t37NXU5F6ylRSQMTEV1r/SmMpapsl4EJQCsrSdLjAFqcc@Q7jWs9nQ7DNb7UOw0zI6HUVhnxWzB9GFtiEwuFrmVLH8tyUFYHTFI41igkBA0hhIaaCTR6EbSwbSWrZLA0ftA2FVJ2wzRbZVFKgQxVb0NlHV9EWtweQJlmfXKjR4KPrAIty2YlGTI7zQPC0FUMp@NUduLNVxqNWwGjtUZIudWIoSnRS7E0lCYgam4GBBklSpa2vhrYPtMFQuj5GUTahMK3vy@oUgs2SFLTXK8KuIYlnY2t9kt0sX6OZSFhjAtCJylFW@Z3bq4kKB31BqprrWnQBYBaCKxlKG6aTkhAkZTDiQwZSMTnQlrjNJUwskzNam6iLAchyqDbUBwoe9iVPJWgPLwp5kTFT5CgqtGXoX6AmFtQY60kNn@TRUQcuAjiDOlGugGkheqiOQC0jhk54KlWZjlQQaFu8PiaDQIwIbuxT10rUNbUBwENN2kJeBKhAVMe522BvWkVUNo0A4ouK5thR7oDkYZ6C3seahv1PaSeZlgxqsBXx8DcnJgJQ8gPX7gXZJmQJgqAiDiopBP/zBn7a7XcBTa7VAtrns@oa1jRb13DJlFrpDhgwLAlWjbAFcHFPn0SGBa1lT2yQgZH3kJkGZoFRvjIHWZgYkaN2o0Ep78jW0bGhcLUfhTM47@zjry1dcmqicc6HgfbkJFUsJUNpU7AR7tgG11FKEEPFMoj9wOgWWMLdY2E59iDwtRZ4uXiiQuWgyuryUSnXLwHDJZfKCt/BDnPOmNiEpbUe2DbUtmCOnZ@gZlmgxsVUxTEWPhCdwhONhqxmOJlHKRaJltdJKdlS9HQmvAS9WIeFwtNyqtM7VUr08FT2YJKC5QTTYXJVIKyoKIHKoUVyn@iDNk9A5vEm4rkCYYTeQ5BicDHgjYab9rrlHiJQd5EsDGQTkUNLWFMWMpJNSFMUEws0tNwbMK@kUDrfAJbUeC4fCsWDRCQOUdKKg2FhPVAPFlmb2sNMCoui2CT2Bhbzbgp4aJaOtOqBxxlmT@Jp6EZAsJBNvlLClYJfu8xE1Sd7kMH4CBaWLYdyEJluy0g40ZBAC0JYde0Yaa8YNJEh5wm4GRIeOicpdqBqIzAtS4wXhKZHPZJG4ogHYmgorJJoqNAJsbiDTXZ4PlA3AsxkOA9h4IwnInr48Aiwt3q2OGwxTO9CW@iAeQBtqKShzQPgovEPBRAbU/mzQsVHbTicyudxkG5tpYo6VqiXeg5D@nHqwJWHhg40JBQ3rKDdMk/XuQO4qXBNjcqulmI4rqKAktgOiaLq/Ic@E23km7Z6w9Gw6bepEPNVinAYKeV57blcoo3RxFf0EqDMKk11TBTRHC8SSNppOHQCupxIXPyLIRAY@ivdkwdMAgMmUodIaOCDVgIFvemqrBzyLudO5XOSd0HTy4BVMHSR7ouMnjZmRqk8yQjLle2E27kWRwBqdxQOdK6KqTnhQ5Qc9HsYs2/05iA0/i9ARBHyTKTkJvPcVnH1DN@YgBUL6aBFkMoTXA2hix6hQQsflqV3UWH0t068iqDM0BNrIfz3HMe0S9BOq0xs0k8ApqRNrtOsc6MgsKccaqY7B3U3NaIJYtqF9prwUUq1BUx1OFYj8/Dq8tIVrUMA6NqtAz/1pAFwXCXdsEJjkv4HAgSCRBDeh4HcRAAkoCYSKdGwSxdsgVI5HeisiJqkpJaHRiXEmYsMVwdwRMZZPlw2jj1KInZFigJoemH2qjraCK/NJ5Mtzuzpf9pNeFw4nLw1Vj9yGFxcXw6VwFST74uJTcK2h6ym6YuB6Sq4EuRAuiS6KEScXhp5TDPSrh@/OPczDaB2rbYi90mfVjMjnpVK2HpfPJfeZwWcURB1INoBO4APwhKOVCjqjUbF6AwVNNjuTpd9A6XzcslTTJcIL@Vrm7y4VskQGtW@iGWkpZexkH6ZJv2JBLwhKa6sXscIX5@mL@sXtRTt2cReOY@xoWa40oVCQXqSf7FrGALrL6PlKKSHVo9HzLHSSzUo4HV6ORAoJDRKSo9HvCtGYzKkdCSsgtSMXF2Egqkuf81bPInzDeCYa9UkF@cCOGXTCSDh5W4D0m9F6NBaGuNFwHEyMSjgMlGkhEWwqNHLmBIEOjl5ywmzEYgKxoWFd4W9G7INfEgwsHn0b@HfjeNLs7V@BdGUtW0NVJGFxbQReU8vcs00PX@MqsV3SWHXobqEE0Nu2fcsIrXF9QPozKbdGMCEyBxGC/LDvQbmqTsAg4o46BAMB2v3IU4Sw/0ZdaAMMTkNTkmekmogMGg6avUpyrjZ0yLuVZMse8wDoPeA0NbkFDXsS3YXILgAh8HkqNT8kWp5BPK0qkVXztTJCx9KSdaRfWyWtfaDaPSQvaFZoSlgdoCqq7KAbKES1XdaCPr8LlFaGqsN1eOCjY4yyI9uRKGqNNa51obKHGgNmyhsDoO7caIG9o4DmgKHceGRb@rVqGToSObkFqIHhy1gHU8jnkRfYqFbbzWzeT995yIFiM95SgLZBrNPEbdktltINzegabBkAkDWTSc7YuzoOlYDO54B5yWz1MxGo1jX00RQPKtjd26gjSvmsr33LCJki@OQlyBo2v9BjgHvKfLz7fgt6CCmXTkP@vbc0XX4hA1imy4ieLTYGcIdsNeQbrMn3itkbTQwoIX9wKxL4yVB4w@R2vQwdKuTKbeGfKWqwkXMfaOdeUNtzzSv7FmlIOJQRtDImSg/KILRTtzi82UAJQ1Pe6OuRYgLpTIWP6xcF10VqQm75hlOi0zccOfUm2bMZ3gTUFxIqE@1UeDGcSiTwLlIQy1RZqq1cp1BKuZhBKp/0BoqgtHoGEy9AdwkCiSBCe6CEJ6AQikVqnh/NHZwWHGMA@mJb0dS@6uzSQJqmo1I07vC9UBwPHCM4VBVHcC2ZseDGwa6xFNe7HH5riF2dLSj0ZPsHm1uNw9rJTkVMDWwrpalNaBttpdEHlVZTbJFNXyF2pAAyN/7nK@3IMJwKZ4QrjX31CmEcL/reZmNvd/2odvSOZ4LQ2Gp/oMmYldLSFABGP6Zgr70GRhg7ltH3dX3brYilLJJemZhNQMPXDV3B0IE7lxDwz6N/H@cHki2h22qxhMFffU8XcBUBcc6AesduLIaQNIfge7qQBUKJ8whJq@l5FtHTn0GYGFsfo5sXfn8kF/OtlL5D5LY@sM1AyW4lifyvnU4H9QHfO0PeVwlsRNrYO0vefAZicuzfJctM0FxgH98K4eMzF3PxzQTNBfbx5Tg@nPGYj24qZB6ojyxPyHCGZC6uqYA5gD6mVcIUnFUZhxUo7L4pFTetucH3RvJxFwk3TruMUdEkjOvlAWY4d/T5lIjdwNHXMY9kpIlQDOITKSzRBrNnDUGQX77gFAt4gX5om@2kM3TGKLJBFAnQZvgEix/OGUHSGnIDWuU4t55PIIglNBBgUn4cOedHNqaiGurY2wfn9ZrRGiACBoEm7fkEg/xIvAq9mZxgo8jwGrQMcxRoy7cZTvy@6oqTQOvKcnKTHEK9y5oI5NQ2vdmciTDeLPkMTuOSDwM23AkcrBcuCE@gU98zQBXbU22aVw1KRsE3GS4E0bN7JhR8cRySGY8/ssT1/IFTMYiIZDaI1SsDze2xq5FOSjnE4qPoX2mzMTugtdJtAnQmU7MhvK/oNzt0mwNQcsfkoFvESSakygucV8BhQwNsCOWGwGh0gZABtVRdTh3RA8cZ5uVncsRkIjNNpTMA9ToF5h@6vwKWKBYIstNsqveBAl0w695zbiGPBmDiZJIrScmzp3CEEmwqPtxxsntAgNB@ezPDbGyiKpyB5UAs9/mff9KGKpmtsJ48IiPDdzSAksQtnXvrz42KL3SbX9cEcznQVJkIQ66voWzJOLMha75jPmrUaVgi0ZOtPurybnUDu@IN2tsDnMdzbinaoK14z/mJlBgReXI4j@lqn7XmQBPs1MgjT4ysN82Q20QGbmOpCkWysLJ5NShDbm0ElFkQRvclNGeAkI1n5JzewBnwO07Cfa0aVRN/9xFhAjadk5uSkjJsuakqD1S7JV8N2kbCvOpSoTFr@Tmw4/I3cTwr0dHkK@5soHM@AXgRLbXbVSzveR/YTQ/MBrJ3Ujf0eIAzPNWKkbIsP4TT0vj9PhBvGYzvuJ9Oqka3R1S0z1DEIi1oJEhanGlPBMikThFWk5sjtPt6385ZmCDprCBnKq1YLJ3FTtafVhnP6Zvm/fGxZ6b4xeL82HyOn5Nkns2S4nP7CT7mRWV2Z/u/0sih61L7spbItAPOe6W4N546ds0BpUGAREuTbWAmx60O5Rqqj24PMTj2Ri1kq7HrAfYeZ8ebXbtvosZtpW5LbhmaamNz1u6TmtNj2@M0cZUF3cZR8W2WsG1Sg@1ewnfNlwRGy8FZknsY7RGSjU9Q4BRQgHOSxn1Eaxk3@LtXuegZ1wq/z@/cPs/N1SNkVEIjllBbcwVou/U1TsWZdrrNp@PV3Hw5LW2uvzsfMGkKPJaXbVUzbLDJ8f4QKUC7tm1@n8/FQaqpsp6gYeuge340N1MmS7rDdPfUpax1DS1f6KZkuN1b4QOrg5LffT5W4vkSS5K@LrE8PcjQJfd5r6i/SllXX@MEGtu2cA4s4Hygn50ntty5k/sLCPYDTmzPL9x2ukAxkyk@QHJfBVit3o088p4/oje5j7peb2KOSK8GNQ8jFAvgcCyua/@Y1FYeTq39OJE0g3b1a4UIVO6VpkDnRfeZKmWZtPSNMaR0@vECqqMNlIEyVz4dNC8VXNr4gLXx@Eyl3WIsuUOJKSAeDiT6UJ9dq/FRucZ@G98eFDCypkIj/6p2M1femaCLm2hoH4LjEB2zEbv6wJyo3AlrTT96mHI902vZRnsikxjyrRKp8HUdakJdtxX63afab/UNsI2NPqgN@iPq30VKox78PoGYfMaKxsTgyNzk/Yly0GVB9YAaVa/sBI6LP07oZO4z6Am4WEzpqq44I7zfR@l5QrRpGNq31AzI0rZKS5i1BC5a/VoNzag57poJNh66sHEYpNm5b9CC9zOucQnUQ7vZecBSDg5FPWANzgyrP9BbBQbZv2ZfQk9No0K21fLc9zEkDX5IyUJy9UF25Fqo0VQ0mT@G@ZWH8BWT2Qfx@VqHq97SpAxO5PCpm/GsWmhK9JgjIJbaBtukp/QVen1AqZfblwPbe9wLNDTwNyc4maKJiHvimSq0dR3vE9NEAW3IMXSwphzZ6ipojmg4M@r63idfvfmNucTd7ctdhe9weEh0jEclcDEdN@LGzvnjEyW@vqUF0fj0/8OsAA3nShnZ3nMuwlejFtTnoP/1UbWpNt7C0c@vNupkau60zlfUPb1n9PSe0rOocfhv9zUP4EiH7015qBCQ/55sX@HqQZJHY2uuZwepqxma9hjqojzk0tEw5g/MbuHK/zZE/Sa8I7kJAe7jqyN20GUTkajvvq/t9JQB9Ey24RimkqC3@0A1HOzh9/ljzbsHYZudqYrV5ksfQB2HpNWmprAbFbJwaQfnnecPJDU1Q8YFqg8o70AZ7/mYoamWYX113KMrG45p0qNhagObbjSim6B9GvOKu005fQwzqA5fdcJZVukazVZP/VqWmors6OpVyhvD4a8P2qWuMKaSqyyxid5JTQVaWaMkMkElGH6Mj937@r/AFM7c0m8MLGv0dcEwOePvD7XyGQJ03Je@Ozk7J5i6fFxW5S0femCawp3LvZebSIFGZTmhpEErke4dAZpYQeZKL5pUvEfpmSo3ZSYwj/YtQ5fuYgAaxFMDCxrAf97gxX2CcMeVb2AVRnYGXTv6dcbttUGnwttchLUubtbiM0m2ZtwEBpqh6cu6@5jbK/uzjg9NgeQenANJpty5zoQyuHd0S1NNm99ZopOZi2V28n4WajTf0nWrp610@DQFur6m2fUNC5fRgwqRaFmK3cIRb5S@XCpykaMbXZDCCY2NgT3YuUWYXS8wTzeZ7OESb/eVrozL6vZUXGGn2bOdHmCeXjrwGMSvB7Ktvh4YjjIX5/QSgsegfCV31dbORC14CD3qumuw@GOiEaDXbEXc9FSbVjN7jvkNh7MZzcbPBk4Pqvu76h4eCAnoRe6iUpbYZd7iU9@Bw/oYLs9Na1LrdCfi7xV0qkMDpu5zbjnnL7d4aBThZtA3B7b7mJ96H/cmBEeO@1fkb9@oIAUTn0Dosp6sOfNHlwODp6BPuT3h2Hmflv1e1Ywue19IM1C/QMCh0n0PY61Dv3woO9AC9DnMSuk/ct4SxyYSXKmxPwEjKFmWUHXVeXgcxnFksIO8JxaIq1q49ya1h/fks2/FkDiZT5W9ByU@dOmjlgaWzdegDt99BULZ@HrX8pVpF@gqDX3gJHC/4kNdRP7BLqLEhoV8gAdY5PXWq9OoxwrdXouvZfyKJmYrYNENbG00dt072T@Hw1Tcp32/kJ2N4ZkGm0pHHmjOEc7oPSZezTQ1HNkAmb5pzDNhDkfQxXyTHQS9xKC/qbRwJvBRedg3XoF6Bv2WCVK1f6Tg1P2UILk/MkbdM1qyBjRrPyq5Y0I/r6wnsqmsQ51r31hejnFTduR5WBUc/et8zX4v4WxQU7Eu@Z71ByFnc7CjDMm0uJdl@HqnI9rK62/6suPuWmXwUy13x6md9LZ1h2hdN20B87YEsRBuTBugcukYVpIRXCQix2LRqMAj4QRdVwcwD4o21uKmO75n12bQhh2CVTvs/Jwt3Q5L6ZJ0xypMLImsXudY8aItYFtDk3bFHvHo50tyvbIUTiTCS@ELvcTSYR9c0aCbmgsuT8B2VHrw/I5JwHSZr95Ht1fiMt9UaPdowy6YZG0w7U51GnFFM5FvjeP7Lk9wBdDf/mXb3cfcVaCwfRVURSAIbuM3@krPuHnK03VThwYo4z5oxAFahcZ35SU2agy6O7AB@fZl44adbp8U3E2R7pkB8HLIbQQ/F7xycRQStzQ4vPJ4bvzl6W7CfiyvUCBcB30drO6207OTwI60W2FgjRcHgwvBdMfCoYd2nO2ytoILL2gTCo22aYZxRbvJMCd/@5d8KyhtRXG3CHjJ0xbwQIq440Si/ZetljGAXHtIPiuW4YJEkMigYwxwHJtht0P@UdygQXtUgSMT3g5NSoZv09yoHbPEFgvjcQi48ausdiJLtaPnb87T9cr3rJ9S/vNPUtFbl3Did4li3hbjzAMp3yFjBYNzEDwODTNxaSjyBP19OqorNG94fQCJZM5kuFXH4zHDMN1WQ7vsaVO5z43uaS8RdFM9e1s1@7RBnxhWuaGtmrSKXUeRiTvfdRsaGLxGCTVvdZWlyIAPtyaOHZaDBHG7qwwuvqWfdq7gtkOMsjRkX1gPmSzRwt0U8MYJqeFO135l3VuKlw0umExtKs0BLRK6ziQz2QoVZ6lRWauSy1LaBu44P/9wMcykExfD1a16yvaIenEx/C6deQtUNyyI9SSFLW9rf/N2KVlNf/liyyMminfhMl/gCWJi6fZw93Dr@KR2cnoMtXDniZ9tw@rLY1mDXET7I3qGRnv5gS6WqtjfIH/8NwCPRNiSzNbwlJpoVAgu0CdQl9ZiQlzizoBomoj9lejz4ttKIHwWwJVpHZV5HLULnQfWITAbUg0LPzDxRALmxnV3VROXqSjjsQH5hMFltHNkKZFKZBUgVgKI9UhSsfsL@5T7PYZiX8XyMNmezgVBivnpnfvhvIhzSXD3Wym3CR3lb15ujuXhchPMA@UGUN/Xi7Nd2907PdqajAY8Rk@SupVizt2ZwoUztjQ@UuttI6ftgW5EHKquiEykCPzV7czoCKKm4twoUCxXOLb6PDJxKOVfFMaMCZSp4DlO9TKnRSRCOUAdpIzFmto401GHgSx6fXQA3S0voi8EtkUftZfxpOhiDtGZOkm8vGIgVpdcXtM7JCHuyuuwHVR/4l6Lw6JhHw1WMMW6p6vyex2bwX@gV/JcmTobMrc7k@oswTLw0xS9CwX2YKNl3kexJU4IcYnnXfTzi@e5QJ7alzKNGNEaTndvEPTSmmzi4REu9L7hKCX2aWDQFkdPmPj6xQ2OR8j86CKq2paMpaGtk7qDB0F4/Rbh290@rqB2xlUzku9Bnhvo2FEBUOAgITB2LDzzqUOynh9JwkluuKdfeF0lTSHY7m53X0uw2bVq0xQDVkIHdRwNJCWWxi04nuJFm1tZTbNBJ2lD983PvCLlJEkbDfhug4TOxBDwZNJXGeNMFBDWrsyehgBd6U0LutWPPPISwRFmO4AzvLaYSADluqrunTpVwpkQGiIuMcca4HqdangmipeFErkSPaevBQDnnAtzoaR@@IM/5WfBXDjg/pnrHqbX4e333LcOuH/fC5EkePsX/lsG3n7O3z6ksMpmD8Bwk3cN5Ht3ZQBfPhNnyoQywTt6i8ri1zbW9JvdQ2bTdA3WZV8eBqoJJQzynKoDvdQ@MMU11TGC8xTGVTjGEzl/AywCfAX8geoNajSUnmLVI3gMQimVwozjmFKSlvIrQz5XQ6cifBrgaUCghKXyufyKlIJMJq49hLQ1uYuLyTnCaLQEMlG4Vs3Kx2YL9wgx0QZjVqnky5w3Ukvyh6z40c/oEsAK3FA4ZxAHtxX5MSCs6kaLLMkxKYpRsSMLS2GUaW2DsxpogxFyAEgUvXVvByaom4ZLKuBjXRk6pDGNPAOoiae@4Rizws@E8hAlABHHjWfWTDfH8fJw3E4TaKDJYDWIZwh2jGAlcR6znn9gF86FXnfPLmLAeL@cw7o6uP/5nAONOGfhZu3Zk3Qi0@fgYGnYs2PdwG0E25BbFsmkMtmUlI8GOFR0UUF@sal/AZTQuEFYtBT10jDt2sbW7ouDw@OZE2EIMjwNFmbh6lrsIpGMn9d9R9jP9yRR17dTx6/Wtz1SBnM1XmmDEOPlNtPZnJfadE7vSf2Mr8ufTZsCZhKS0o9FTHPbiW1ajTaLfRyaCgBu8GXBM6lGord35/W16oUemkn@y7xTskLJZWQucF3YdEZWeDqbmMVdb7fBCZ6@aSe9bWcZcXwGnL9Zjr@Pve8/08U/y3N8sIu3r0GgjdHjzdPJe3Y8QNmTKZ4UnWrCM@blF2SNl1UJszpOsCXMrJYK5oa5ZZk9dtTd@ecT6YCPIXmHRtoc0ibhzEeZ6HQln2Y@3ImHEZv@@KgV94yRHuROU5vCjbsd3ts36W@FT9qmpjqRqKC7ENM7KGch7QdPLPHB5Mr5kPlbAW3UGYdJGmuP0IFgN3WBH/jCvHNZYnS0y@EA6HZomGw8irapeK4j0KnY5oCPvSrsxaAPcB16HCnYWyigZSUgMtAz7GXlHA8zcSmR7LdzkWE02VOGbbULPU4kGgfR9J0kjQ@FkfFUE9CrmvNKgMNSZk@GMmDVZNfwTJVhdK1Ir@MC8lFIdjPfW68LgAyjNqMlPnIRPtW987uw4kssHPcp04zGw0nGLSn3aC5a8UEDUUm20cP1sTT00emopLIFj1rgnXlHtfpJLBV0M5yFnuPq@CDXfNP5PAHKyOdyUtXbyjCCRyGU6kgn8A/fnF2Ho@IMi9MhQe6RMO3p04I8WSg7rlAan7QzJe@KRV/OTYqGYhGPU8BNpWCUQIrHjrUHTlARIp2@bLLIgI5bslmS0WvkIqLHbceKskQVu@sbprNYjMY04EEBYLMgaIdcKp1rEcHTCSOpClQS@tp6Gx@fVZOdS8lkHdyUSJQt4XjmBmhTOBIYFcBGhSglQgv6BfyVMEf8LNmke6bsEiUr0IknADU3mOQUTquAfAFaUKlZ9UngpIixgOFULRZLbm1MSvsiA75YmyMQAe0cKe7ZCEBfd1cgUA1lNEBtWEpbBXn57KWi6woQCHimj0fnygNgMisa9051jo9PXaQUQjyLO@42Q8jo5GmMW@FbDWcrllJlGhor34Fa8/EC9ZqOq9mMUv99Kpkq30aWtMooBbpmtBpZ6lWkWHY5FlvSlyNLOmpbT57giNrdEihzjSQYqEMASixp0TLwMyh/lSW9vCSvRZbalcwyxYBXMJFvIcL3dip5uyTfpZaegLIUBx@LC53Ikk0HJaWTSekO8octZCkVB565xRN/6KxmTH5JjcUwD8mlBmbg@9TFcYy6zYvjFA3elV1bINXtu81tShXza2LmjGlOQNe75HdYOeyw3CWjDQ94fBZjdl7YPeofT/glLqxntB5IsYPGlzgZ8njB4spplLmukInwk6qAgMMIEBFf43I0CsLk178OSXnGxKf5bMSIPc2ly7FwTgIzHezr0DPQw1PLoiXeXmwmrpnSyeQ/Jc7lTvJT/fDq8PBt9CLCiiwc2jgQpRXxAx6n/bhrlWXuudiPv0Kh5ZQQSi1LT1ZTqY8fP4LFAdd5NVkF8cGv6HkiXD@PrDJWXV1djucLy/Fn4UYgW9FIJhM9ZqqaYheqabfb8DN6dLB6JMSvp08pLTD/4Z9xPzd91@G9IIjrG/pGuGs5F2IXq7K8HFvJPNPLyUw687d/vXgXvz1srP3t7/RTyiI@DvDxs7tX6D6Wct8tLn63vr6yEgdCcvfh@8N3tVptZTOeOzzPPV1JpBfX/tP/ubiYyaxlUot125bq4fOrt2ImvSIm//YvwoeHrxu2DYQo4pVlEjjxXoCfxHI5dsU@w3XVYfhP7s/tgFtGd7PzGU@nAnulQsImHM5lw8cfwvOrbZFJ1aer/@UPDz6FnFA1kzqz4OmEPoXyhRB3ggPest7bdagaWkOw/F1olKpUKuBc/S//HuJXXwAeDBmtwa2a83DlR6FqokJRvoSqeXBImQyk@3//5CdCqDoMfQ5JkhQa0V8D3XAVnkhPGDpS4mpBNIxnePQ7XsPANS5FSpIyF159Bqobq9b37gFuqFdmBPz8eve5irncQI7HwlXhtoXX3/0ff/fHf/eH9PfH9PuPeKJ4fvHZx03GFOiB8SqVns3Uw97U@1EyAVfSbx0hfE24JQsVKvEGz5XPwqGAY4oO/p25JPHfvxFOCHnH4qIcqk9UxkVIKqwcPBs@@mLjTHu0DY1J6ifOpv28yvBfmCcL2LfACaHvK5UjB/9eNfHv0MY/9mCWHziYiT2FaxH@6B8u/xXvi@TjehPI7LX4G0hfIXQeOq/Xd3T8@9SjPwv/mp/wb@8z/n1y8O@khX9Hn/Dv5DP@zZZGCK2trYVisSNQGV2mfcx1Cr9ksuG@@cwbEkK/1YsJ0BzqscTd3XnywzBWLrv/oEeV/Te8uAtyVL9LJNY@VGOxc8rZedXN4lpi5SB/wJ7VqzzXdE82PqwB9tja@dpaxdigX7JRxStR/1A9X5vEQWjq1WfPYthknwGKav38XAjdYq1U8LaMt5aN94wopuj1C0p46LKLQgi13SJXeovcg76NgW9C6OPtx0jsaexpWktfp6Ur6eqVcTD@PzgYQoA6TF8aVrqX7kltEJksrZymR@nRMN03DqQ2OBX4S/fBqaY7w3Q3rad1SRoNJ1Dd/98/MJxXBwZgMyCmM0w7iDjdgWf34OAV4OtA2pfwp6bT6SFkcpi@hv@0hgKcjt2j54cGi97C9fHu48XdhXDOxI8KKApJKZxMh5P5cFit5/LmJzEeblych@vlUMq@uEhxFYplVsp08OLdXaOxtb/ZaKSQqZZiz2KJZ3BVqrE19/E0VC0/vSglsC69Wg2l1p5eVLMJdOdjUE0Z9It94zXGCM/q4oUANuHZGf7Obq5vuIsc6Lo4o6vBg8/OUtzr5sy9buBKXd@DYMLBQBv9R/pvH/zX9f/qlEXO61HGIrd3axG6ovgXjd7e3d6592o0EnFfImvwhx7wjlFu76roJKBbcJ1HovXo3R33g3skusYRVjGNtSpFHgNCkw3xVC/CZcbAeoq4E28XF8N0Olpugo8/BC9/oTmcaJlWtyw1cd4NLAZpOUoguZVyecV1rxbK5YLrlvL5cnnZh0rDi@sEIMWWW2Xk83LIjGIeOPdH0jjwQofbhiNtpYNfOXhqmmD9ScX0ly@@V6PRVq1GA/2zX75cQEMK4@KWSjEHPunCly/QDsNRsAz3DXdatQh2npTKjNH3ZFt2HCsCtn/8IowLyeyLcBTDM@k0AmN8lltby69Uq/kVcOcL0WhZXOIrYyLdWFGK3i2lRF4MsNnCITdIKqxGyfcujOEstMaeVoHDbbzY7V2IqM1WctFIc6REfQ@pWOQ@bCUfKcSK7l9lMcpS1WXm/p2fZ2Mry6vLz@r1cY@NQqJ8K1eku8qtXMJxhLtyyz1ZFlf6yk@eZItAlkK6fCE0Gpu1k1oDP9GBc9QghRl6krgRcP7RtMLnNOiTK9bPsSD1i3C4VH7G67WQY6Fw2YVLhEFwsUKRyhsCy1Lt4BL/IWBFvEKoJC1nsoup3PC7/FYaLKJlvM7PzwuZQmwZxNpysViv18l3jWKc94edOp0uVkmcS/lcPYF6zOWwsxwymbSaDS0LJq00Wk2zNk7WWjiAtgieUKWsifPqtqJp3kG@N4altW/UtrIohA73ahtbJ/HMGqDMbNc24pnj0/WQhK@58TsFZ/H9aKu2eXAKEQ73tmrHW89332ydHoI/HvsJV/9QVgZKQ7kZDG7wvaHQtaHa8uWlbJoNE65h54df/u4Pv/wffvjzn//w57/7w5//8a9@8ce/C7@/hN/P@fPn/66Yw/uvfvEv/u0Pf/bn4Pkf4fcf4PfXv/rFv/oJ/9H738Dv/wr4/Y37C8DxnwC4fu9Xv/jDv/jVL37/T@D3r93fn8z@/uCv5//@@Kf3/zDeH/7bh2F@/u/h979xXB7sz/@M@@FzBv7PONzv/8kPf/S/8///5P6h889/@KO/wZv78rs//@Gnf/jDT3/nh5/@7Ief/lNgm3/4q1/i/x/@1T/8h1/i///6b/7hr/6nf/i9/4Ucf8od/8@//nf8/ve/87t//9N/@fe/84t77r/74P0Xj/D/xT@Cz@Pz@Rg8jynXt/r84kfl5zehxjgV4AFgpH/@w7/6Z8BLf8Tf/kd4g38/6Gf@ix8SI4MzERt7/oyxLylQ5dLPvviggPJ/Rl/wZl8msZFv2vP91S/@5V@g9wTsPwtiSEuzsEsI7Kf2M2wMfsaCsD/D5vTDL3/yw1/80x9@@ac//PL3UMImVorxWjwhfWXcCgBzj4BDwPxj4ABQWsMp/EW2KGTAsbiG4yyCFPv4Eci6CC6wCpaFXBbeQvU6GRYX56nqReqiyq86vCdTVfRJpi5SGJ5MgVHRYN@BQYa/Z8@W2XeJBH@O/QSpSqghjzHoaCSw3pb5sEkMjVf4DYWVIrzhQEoM@scYD4pB0HqMVSqVmDCsQBiBwivGGbJqAc1iNAQrgBcj8TjxRgE0bjZcJywQsxI7Yo3lypBHjKFHlTAwzBB6HYlSRowVKpuQYGW4yRAXIo8JH@H5sVItVIZVRPc9ZQFwxNYhSYCqYO6G1e/hvUI4AV4Ybn4PWSlUYrFqAXwqVFRKLd6gNKUcFY7KHmNUbvQHcx0eT58x9p0oFURuqULNMBca77Ex9FMasHkK4RexZbc49O856beM8aHah0Qf7sfDn6I3xXcBAG8igavH4AfVCADPIHjIUcUoWXjEOAagXMwdf/A9SDuJCTGq3xi9QPqQh8dda9XAC6LD4iwtLYFrrSpmxQOwc5h1VbId2cLJFVLgSkzMF0X0xsU4ytIhWULLm8twl@B/a5EW1HJyLAtLYVRWwsxLIxHLGitGiHLvFY3Kskw5jxGcEBr7c@WbZshAa15hUSFCZ@9HyZ5WTBOer@zuujEEBTkuinEpz8fAo665/c4olSrfSyurAjzpfYDH/rsH0EM14KfgkthYkaDV28QaNVxwgkKVF6pVd5aPSUL1eOsEIpwcMCmTTjLQqm9XVjMruZVcJpvP51Yz0kq@uJLPFbIg9PLpXCYjFVdWioXi6h1l6RkIjnhpuZlbq/6Tmeu/@yfzrvm@eAnVt2yYZIk7oTpMJFIZynFFyq2WRxXIB3kJVVIVuf0wuk3g4k7hghaT3eK6JciWcJtANl2AiwkLAlsAL7gALc5vMHfSffeg7M4@4gdV@AykKOWAEaLCBTACxyaYk5eA1fYEZM0TiTtz@bEzjc4T3N@3DylAJehsD9d5OgY7Mfh6wnWlJay5O9OqgkCTNedA0rqA3ys4rwtrKT90PqaNHv/K4IZlgPr942HWZf2KB22qfE@SH7Qj46Fhdl91evdAnJp93L2jWP9oGLb6TcggDspygHW4WZphzANYZaeH95Tylb9fGGc9acMwgB/tPt85CTxPtmobO0KerR/sb049ci5Qju1tbZ/4r6s81Iua81G829rbm351H2hCLbLcajwO0hFu@IzTRc/k0gcPREo@MCILXVNqjS2hjZyD9s7yIH0vKlV52NEHwN5gATYU1qisn0vlUL1aACmzsppbzaeLq9Bc9wf9AZKCnQ4KrDtwRrsHDIUeK4jZVbFUlIRXuPqtKPFdHKot7IDp1cePEOABFo5gKW0ww2502qDSxE@JDUx2ryc80AudltrtQV5uDA9AaMoyg9@3XhBfCV7Owx4OT4P8ZkK0OeA436d2WFpI0gBdpljIFYrZTCFeKBZWcmCh5uJSJi6tFlaL6biUlgpSvpArSvHCSjG7ArIRQnPFVSEEMkTtpFIg@iVRpKeqt/Cg4DU8cdlI9qpCiA9wQH@L38gMyb4HVI6YLVykIZ4o4MpeplYWRfwKbRq/8QoIZdZioe3tjfT2tiiu4wsOSG6kRbGNL7lCOr26LooKhWyA@M6IosHjQBCAOfwlnV7fEMUBR4B7nUWxhy9beVRdRVHFl43a9jamc4kvGYwPYFc8hL9o3ssqgOn4ks2S7iuKn3x0AFfjCa1QTrfwBdPEkG0esgFhovjcy086DRiOOBzHsOOVtVYTxV3@UqthyAsqeI5n9SW@1OgSRQtegAdFsQuOrqUouig2wYmcKIotcLVGMvjhocy4LVZ3ZFEccQIhiURxSNBy60oEpcr1x2R2dnbkntNWuvwaWfzZgqxBiDocbG03nz9vdrtNa1Tben6EIS9e7MiXo4HV7DbdaM0GXAbEgZCr/mj6gjzuNhqyNjfkJYToUyGNUUPBvDXkT5An9@piIv3GCwh5ASHzJoI4Nrj6ANrEa70Pz3W5SSHeRSH0HDabYhl51BmZCg4EYZOhFVLloE9fbllGGV2ghbPFcCQcH51L9fjnMoWwPmOR6G26fIcgnQh9YAaFJKg8t6PzYSVdB91bKuMYVWSx/1QEySeWFuWnkSG682IJtO8VMVrCj/MYnTALJ6Sng4KYB4m2DE/xKQm3YSQdTjMGt@j5av2puIpIxKdPEyLkBV4BRIaI4moRERZXQRMo3wE9HOiZmgNHaTQikRtFvopGeZn4B73Y2dlZ9JavClOpjE65ExnGhxWeG6ZGy58h89OY2rgTeNByDIvj6wIFPj9Nl6iQkHyBkmepVHQNJRLKEHh@pEH2JCsl@LdspEI@msRF5A2j06CvSrCP3kj82dmMi18s6IFa4hnuBqGdoN6yIVKQ7ZJwgqokfSyT4QkDTfy@FG3ZBRuFH3VCX4NSQLEsCkLV1a1ws3Bye6Bj6ZL4xSun7IacKEMnuaPg4p6W57fB91wmt4b4UUjV0L2A4xEoCP3k7kHyVLfljlK@TZwl7mjbMO7exM3RapvJlSq45HaEEmJy9Iby3KhWK41KX@mbzghMEdKGq35c6AfZOuOQuA/EWwoP/SYUJV3W8SgQ6kaXhqGhUG3j9uf1yvrtoFQC2LuyUlEsy7DEkFjuPNUrA8rgoWLhro3dg6UOU3B7RKv38WIL4TaAard3iarF9HK3co7pfsHbWkIU64nE@Zc66LyVdHkUkiv2oEmHTbB0E5TyfHkIftLqSlmDovKtL0u0AE4u91iz0vwwLFsVc2ApZQL/okEf1kg2oMWcZ9LFeEaCXgp6LwiC3yq8r8BPgl8Gfqv1xcWIBnbGMJ2U4pIixR1jSwfipEslpBEQl17hKUdjmWUt0jaYvJYgWkOzKWPC0Fh7zFTjvQjEOlJkjYNHY5@e5hNsRYqWg3SPRMuRRRat2MqncqfCIh@i5U9AaGsp0k6uR5@ulNuRddaIggd0wvDLsPwK1/qpaOZio5Lm@v@SPeifpxfzUvw20UjcabLtLEmrmdL5YOk8IUHJ0l@6a@L7qlgHEt8JYCoEx8ihBy@Dn9eyeJ8/7rXHfmYZ9DJNgQqRipmyCyKYbvuOiCyC33DjC8Ei4fBqJhyOhssAtQjeJCait9SqwyBrwk9AwoDWACKmmIFwS3EGoK@C7JvJAbdx8pIQuhPaqm2ylaIQuhXubu/Wqp46@JKNRnIs4b0@YawbA2s3RXN6yUaILZIrkaw@Y7VKrXtUK7ugtQ2ySVMCu@DbCxOpxW@dOYytVT/w5wVOG0MyAicOzbOn1mLV1IUgithI3CmfSCEX5bbw9yE6RZVt3HZQUECzL71CWsmlY/q4wXk9@v2@qt0WsokqmUnAN3d3oRiUDVeQVFNEqdYBLdwQQrrhOnEWwAEpAzI0lxPRZFaYeVz8sPqh8OHV6cHpwTZ7li4VSgVOhgtuxcalsBQGE/kZKG/q0ZYQMr8YOel7/UU5VDLD2ZVwdkILv6i4O@sjyASRc5wjg1/9HIzhehRclYr0VFotqbY7hRUp2QNTsaJPpXymlElL0ZB9h9t@M6shekr51VA9xFGurEbBTZMvGSlUTbne0irGSvA34N5cyC5@CWXSBSFUePXxC2PeV6fVDLlSKTezS3drd/BfvTtfW2N3NBZwR/94S8HtjgPQP0bwXugxvibgxjDj8Pr3iTX@v0a3jQOeczEPFRH6CDLBtj80PjRCQqgYBismzDI5N49D175GFXxZpz/FXsa/D2OPZdu2l/03eF2GMrNcFQyg5VQqdRF9nQF1vVjMS5mQ8OvZK7W8ILDlhRoL84PKeF@Hx5T6W8vCE9@BwwGc5YXE5vHBxsutE@zsFB2/48s2DvaTGISfmh3vDWxpimxpI/dbsyOEwj7yZOOQGWBxbR5SnDPaFUq@NE7jprK02y65H2SKXzMpmcWJyVwqvZKSckwqlNKrpUyeySCHbDwFwnUtYVRGxdowzBE3siIbUYq8UEMYDNtTwfK1lRJ7frhHMeiAiOWFza1XB@xgf@9d0vPl/ic7u8fs@GD75Kx2tAXleLV1zMTaMds9FtnZ7snOwekJq@2/YxB8VNs/2d06RgQpAWUYKn2cYL7Fw9bskZ1CjdAms2fC2zZaV4oz6S9bppzCc3cnvXX8Co@C366Y9B/oKthUQYvquLbA1SuG6OV22xJwO6raYgtoTi0sQ@@Nu2F7aXuV5QZvP6et3CJrreyHV1krva9n11aZlnb/mLbSzx6xxcXFC130O4BgMXyDLuiFGxnAb5yn3fdbC5H8ClsGMy6zEh2H7B8cLqS9t4Wzo5MFyQ872lzI@C@72wtZ/2UL3lb8t@2zzYWc/7Zee7mQH0fb31hY9d82tzYWCv4bMOlCcYxzf3NBSgsesa5BwVqgLw1Gtnf3ttgyAEXLE6E4eoaOKW8gRASUIn42CFmwy8s3PSNO9kBzNAXdVr4G7YFPQC2gWnaOdK3H2bJhwg0UPgCGaIKvoMtWtxV3seIZVdCzCLfCAhZoAQsE8Au4Kx3h2GKFZaIMghc6fI1EhJ9ZGGfiqU17T7@z2Rpq2lVghjgdekV7kCGG4n5yVFi4c1FGOjTC2KGF1QQKVg8TLTEaxY2L@6d7ezwxk7TJiEiQjKuWc3AaJmCDIsIdiw6@vHJ4tVBdIK0WXK0CP4sq3E3UpjBdm0gKKOfCQgsQTFL3WtbiDLWqOE7AI1584RsiABiCwZ0GF9@xGYm0sKxdxWlRhqJIzK2DbV5CnMKvsMlajjJMlChFwXyrxZcvzHu7cCZfrclXPcxxu8h5tjg@ntMKwkbRb8HbKksQdCwAxVxAjonFIDYUh8IC5VoAosOPnyLg5bIKCaXD7MkTyscavBXDlATGi1GKLIEgiMAlGJEPkflZW6TsRhdSy7i4hpba0Lmq2I/wY3CbI/8EFJCs0xmdqlW/FfrVuaCDgVmeEshuUKeNdQ3ubKYB7ygegZPjrAnNJM68QCmPgWiJxZkSZx3wnpKpDVUHzlWssUz0WAEaI9X@/iavIX7cD/lzDyoxyL0SVRgIiyfYfInRFxaaFpjZZQ8K5CFBAd8i00SQEBzu4XhHmxRtmbcXZEuM/ZiYu9slj494bGAHl9OIrHhCA@cVt7jkWR0DzeB3kWH7rQB6zpIcWSzmQvhc5oJtTcIlEhzuzuPLrxRia7oUi99cChTL95Zi65HF@M1KAd3amEWgFCDiI4A3BtB0m6zNzDwU0BcSCirNj0MBHeiYl6CNTyB4RHzocsfxE98eHzrp0nRThnYLNcilAo8y@dqafG1PvmLzBR@ZgU2QWWFfWBNdUh5cuFOfFcDR5rJyMmJn8pUGaipM8eJ0fAnMUwCeQ1HJwZABZ4UxSpCkjZ/skPv44agKq203dve3TiZDEV/SbrgZ7zmGrlEa0UkwN0MYbkfwJernKNJBInB9M3LI04gTPRvHJ0dbtVdxyF@UrY1bwLQOADe3JUyU4M5LAXx1pQX9cTvOIsc1thxlTzBnceYOFuDLo5PQDFsBVPem2B6YGUoqzUH898mWFMIWKcxJSoywSJR9ubiALjW9yqS@@SXbz@qr2TYbZVdR2eV4fB3ElfKegNnnTZMrGwjZ5uczluYmdplOsxUryxylBxr3MG3N4qdy3WHfRt2it5/YNMgos8sMt2@jbHFPX4F@cVK1eViLpL4R@QB9sRmDH3bnNLgXI/0c2ZNCPQWL56WtfGtevqbRTuYlwfOyRonO5uHX7oAomEvC1J5xOsTGMB1Txm3VbuABDaMeopclCHycJXCWWcTAj/U40RKdQYMypdHAg1kbjYitaB1gVmNgtaDLR3XZdsHwwtAkD6SGhI7JQJc8qD9NBrRV3AaNx15CrzOFEE8ZAW88OTFCKQqCnzPbUUzKVSAbOE6GX7EOJggG9sQ7VCtuTwzkOFpyteJtGduDh@x84vgpjmNg9@JzvEE8z/r6bDonzGebOWF4yuC8KN62@Tlhl4P@vByAYLgnxN34OidENw7mReCnN40D6ucBAp4HCVyvR6Lzqx7a1WSNB47fIvqfWAPFPUtq9yDAgqBcuhwYqOvQpgJM21LxEwjTiPyt9xAzMowGTgHw2So65iTZbqnqNHoPk4uItrHSKf9sWGr1AOt3UqYQjQcQBjC2@TGw9@FkAaSQwzlIQuyYeN8bAbV91MiC03jH8ZN4iIXeBvNuHMEwH4DH0DEsVr4HvIDnj/khPjPPaXJjdKVZxiF/HHTH6pcmTmq7D9orhBQNEvQ3TT7xrcknAuljm/xRSVfY@WQ@6rHAewk8xmX0GviPSsjL9WRq0W8qcZBrFOXqHvbFE3UCyfCTNCaT9dG4EsjnKa8ohB49HikkEFcQ0TfIF6o@d5//vNjj/me5whKSH4dLvHFroMH1QOYFPAOk0cDDcxsNOjWx0cCRpUZD5ClQx4sdXrDTdRsbD0uCltowKDQiJmQxLiYSteON3d2Eqotxfqp8RbQdw1IaePiZGMe54YpIAquBMD1FMyuiu2hPthnFFu9PoxZIAwr49UQIiKeyq1Mi41Nxv55cK1gk4xFFMqYSG5/U@YjUjig1PJTgoZQsfuSdl9AGncqGx9xZioqChp@X734CHo8vmTg1A4f03SzwdG0a6bPxrBKeJXo00M@tazz0Y08lq5pG@0TvFB9x5tAdt7XjUA8iGHMq5z7xkL6qxehEt7bi6lk0PJQUx6d5uhlLuiUN8LunoPFDUMYd2uTJPm5@497YpI3DmFNZHQsWw8TCn4t48A9UwKFhwt0//Afc/vE/4MYDgNDLE3XgxtN/MEbHdbgHAYGLjgKCJ7C3OD55tC8P1f4AB26Cx0u4mtw4W9jlY0mo16fASenHKYoQSQ2PcI64eKMxsSRC0W06dmj66CGEn3f6ULQuzApZOisbsxlQHeYhnXueUTT@W6ikgCKGotl2cwNx4yITuRJCcaVSHYzPAO94IgbV5yk/g496IiIoSdyPP@6vAqcXVSbMC6QIGA88M@MIfJQp@PVKUu6jJV8FGddYEIorbnPyjatu7814EIOnqEWFByyp/9/YScEq@a/UVPr/3iiaMX3@kU2ZB0yYb7ZWfotmwX9T6P@bQv8jFPrfmjZ/j0o@jXK2xU@p619Vw79d/SKZN4Juw@pe49Bb5sfoYb8lRWD1m/QAL9fn0kO6wNf7Zw9NJtit/8heWvh16qSdP9s2arXaSV@yjp7XurVe7QgPilpP78XOLlfWN2/Wn6@3a5ub3RfdjX3ldaG2sme@fFt497zz@ZMC2vvOwYv3nzWz1RPeHpk3Z8rhTVYp2LXB4NPuzsjZWT/tbxzn3q3epLe0XGdd@bSp2ZuvTt6@PHmeO47dfHpx@OJzP923DztpudjP7rzKv9kYnelC7lo9bW/vqQf94/bWaaa/t6m@245tpPeOi6@l9N7Wzfvsxk0sl07tmi8Pnh@dXja33mtHu3vv2hufDDn/6erG3E21i52Ny6M3wkH2tbTz6eCgu5UpPt9J3Wx2zHY6s6NZucu3R4frp@92ei/lrf527rT49nJ0mO@9fn3t7Me6K2f5wSt7JabXXr/OvNSfX19vHQlN2TixssqZ8Voyb24OjWJ/VXm5v9Ptv7YkPXWQexM77p/cbG6ta59Wh9nTd2evb1aO3w1evX7x/iCtHh83t@S82Wxnji9PVoRWP7sbuz7dOi3Iz9tnr/vXuzu5d5upVz1lv9Y@1K6ed3feG8eHe7u1rD3Qpb2Na@3d897lq6vNjV3NOLzS9NpKKqedtN8dHAinL9TmprLz1n5Ru@y9S@XWr1bexdrm85PLz72rF@vHpweFzPBwlDY27KPmTme4eZTPFFIt7dPR547xSjp9HctfX77IqO9qnx0h@3mUK@5p75S@/iLW6r4fftJSsVNJ2ni/@/ndu@Oda6tZ008/vdk@urRetfUD@yB99OLlq6Z2VXAuzff68bHUSj9Xrl7F0rIwPN2xoY6UEzm3etLfe20ON41PR7vv7fzn2PXZVVbZvDp6U/t0lG7e6OZb3dpT@xvp9oFce2M4W4Ph81bx@vRqR9v7dGC/E15tSbncttGx1ztvVopvU89jnavnb9el42F6Xz/qrOSt/Tevz1R1q/f29PNRK7f9xiz0Hb37@vNpfyu2tTfsfVYK6aZ2/O5KF05zx0eHmRv9pdp3tneOXuWdg/Tem8P2zkiqvVakG311Y5TbHFr57NnmW@vd1Y5upt6pnwaHaeU61n5nOiuv1Wan9UZt9V8Kxy96p/uHb252c3nreV9X1w8L6f29nY39bnvl5Wj31WBrr3nZfr77VnlrnuSvMlvrZ/nNt8dZ5@TqpVNsXfezh4XYidZ3uqcx4cWgN1g9PLM@vRm@X6n1m0r2SHtnjFal/sYLMzN8U9s6@Ny9OjSNfWk7M0qd7hlXWvrzyc3nHTtfG8UKw1Onbzgn0jAnvRayN59N54X54vXxwfqLg/cv5BVVPZMvj9@009nTQkrtWdndfP65tLXd6X/qFxXp8@arrJzt92L23lWqvdE@fXN2pV32X/YvW0KhaLfWd98PZGOrmZHS79Y7Wzllb33vRFJOuy@PVzb304dv24enn4Yn7Y23g9M3B2p66/JFca@78vboTfHl6vsT@0Q@M96@tPaFYSFr2FK@mLvJHhcLBz3rOHt2WXTev7zMr2tnTenFbqavbKvW28KocGV@7t10b46VdLP7fPOTfNTZAkl6epiWc4Or/eGxkH1z0r9eNddj765aL9/qklY4U1dTJ58ui1e93subzdbKWe3zJzn3/FIpHm@nmtp27nnsaOP14WV38@xzYaWdXt97I78dbvWcd8LrHXXzsnh2dTAcSa@3j0f9WlrXctfHZ7nrE2P9@GznuNB71bQ6zZ3LHsiG/uj08mZwvaOs9oY3hZe9yzdyeu9tYUO3Vw7Twgtlt98@Onn5thbrZJSic33wbt88K5wNc68KxlnROCioL2ud58PXB52t9Kqpnp0MT7d6qfUNtV8AmXKonVobB6933p@9MNNCRs@vf94wcqufYtfDd/mz1GFsb/CudZLpn1nWzlvV2n57ffj25XFtN7bbHD0/vJIP3m3ljvc3NuwXsW01r4x2sjd2bSOrdQzB7q8P94eWWcy@v9rrQk9gtIvt5yfZM92u1To3u4XjrVrtud3cfSEPh887q9BH4LV19saoCL/mhwAK/Pw//pD5ASNC3@42jSHIS74LUKA9XQLt6RL4Li5aIs2XH/86tSycBHcz0LeX@QDPoAnKGmsbqDwk2a5/Ui9@qCPO@gZEV9HVMkx6Ilp310YbDT4N7jRehfsM6cuRytDUDBW/gYTfY0Cb1Bp/5C0pHOisP0J701H6fI@Fip8xcg/WpU848K9F0cGewkKrxbzvaybp2Fj/a5sfQYEw9W6CzgnuskSi1dHkrg0OrU2uj8Kxf449pqCpMg5@YBLSXkOW0jl3aSp9Ew8zd4JfX9p/zjSDfyDCszhkUCZGdMAKDlLRISsKfoPPVq8VbURf/FDaSYGv@HzUKsigHy7vnvSjw02n1oaCuqFYUwtATR7Rm2lNLT/Ds2@eLafcKVZUhhqy1VQd/MJzg@@WaPAUvTVv5uTaQ9r@607QcsUINRs6Fjjubl4a4ttULKQYLTNv0a4TjgBVQ1RRvdWGy8smoaR1V4y/BDAvm/fjVvvd3xbqCdxtVZnAawCtBkArmpCembP/zqZFjj5QWeCT9Vtvd08a7mdh@BLDiS1R96y4DFC57L2ZZV6CQP7dnM8uy8QVBpB9HHbkp2pDUa8NzssirXvE5ZFQ22hhj1dbJoFraKUBYjNpNcr5Sp2vIEzT0j2P4H6cJ5wTngRy9WRM0AV3QYXPA4@MxxdocpDZ8iLijqUoBECrOb2tIVOL/X7LvHdPzTQ1Wb9CV5kvlQV7wWoFKos@eBEoBw5l@WVx10@SjYDlhqj@MthxRkXLrxYCcBfEetV8qmNzpvX2GIfXsJ80jo9hGr7VpWlGKzIOXvaW3PCyRb2UOPxUUgc4ktjBlbWGNeIJ4fBMpFwGEFynQzJB0b3VqoFSV8bUQHS0qCeQC@DbsueFZw0o43zG2cO55UktEjvQCqD5WeWLgRDq3M9WnSd1vywEekeDhZmIOiaOt4QInKll5hgmEKHjchx0Y8QjfHXqDFX4Si@fixin03m6Dv/safClxBfuYoNScNgTRUgUmzFa6FOZ8zONoFW/6WBSY9ajisIV3FiFKvEiU8HCR3@mxmIT9RRAfq4i3SQWI2pH5oSCGPJL5JLepT3B0Jo4qA2@FJd1@AouTmthikRrkNCXL36DgVefGw@9TZjAEv735JHBOWfytuwStOy9e43Qd1PImCi@VL2bXUtP@0/BADduTHWoaBEQmA383I3JwMtdsmSa3EEQ/vIl8MbKpry78mpxMQKxzgkuVaizJywira1FVhMR8vquEI36jdGNnglED0QGIV2tskhmOZL1Iq9gZECZnUSwMh9BhiNYWY5IHoKMi0DKAQauYhCS71iBc@0k4kIAsY@3PgmDH82Zk/pyJibV19YKuMYz4DkVOTM/68vZWAYic9QLsckQjpYHBPzrkyUC5NlMoB8JoFiJZQEFTzo2GTBOdSrATzSY5kp9buf0W1NevH0aXudD0fHbnYp1XsDyIqfyRekmA7fpWK4nfj/NpK@ojf04Sy8jm4OOQE0SUuspuGkqzr@i53ZaQL/yVK8Y2BxBECgGiAgeHjXOLh/q65rf3tkhcIcG@HiZ40yKswKYISBRQGIUIDKIEKKB2m20@qYPB11xIcpXfPMOjBLZxxln3D8A9YRqv5cSiTFOPpzhBnzuV8yoD@H0jUCExt7uOj7ebB3hitnd/edQhQtYjjgb371iLnKMfhE3ZJ1/WUV1VMgCyDZu0Lhl5VU1mT56eum72DzkLvw0dh6RSocQjEd2tUPiC9VpqIaLjZPS4yPFITrSh758gEK0DHYGu1GYrCE5RvwDxQX@PTDa9EaxiVTg8CO6GUQKIc1Ojmr7x9sHR6@IcoeN2t7hTg0xg4HZkq02oy/WYAPRdUXjnapPTwG73y5@qhzLJDe9z6vwj7gjLP/0ISceADYopEG@0znC8nKmn4Hn3vMikETxoUGpaLQVcw5uXLvqg7mFsecg5LXIc@12hW6e5vWE1OHN9oSeHK2ipCNaGoqthx1gbPqCj6xzeZLy8K2DlUmfP6SWi3pUl/jF4t97y2boI9DIR/bAxNlhpS0GyS@3WopNpx6MqQ8oFa1DibiSJUAo8Jlf@rH84HtT/L7XxUHfwKRON@3rvWM1d1JZBO2R0@5H6bgBBYlj8XSkW0@tJLXITZl/k3pCdVQnVcb7EuOpXfLULiE1LnDZ5bRCptbPLycUsXnkUT3yXHLd2NPMuHriLyWnmutAo7d7eBgRjYVwqUMVhtVEB3EYowlZ98SrsideKx63xPnK3cNKmUvYSY3M7XDG/adrMLfbQLbIzNgG7Vwh62tgYf3zF125wRfqKflGJ8/EIHjilAao0x6cJz5xD9W9nIGYQBrSbplzN7k6dSo@voiLkCW8/EQDugbtwnRHBVQdpMV4c5pbVlIlDds1FAOeKFbdXthqe42cIMedmdWe3tCFQOjLNxyOdyXwbXw8oQI66fuZFUKNHDLWWSmA66qJBESI8nEN0mlA3GIZKHuqM78YhdliuIXzdDKV74BBUee6JS4KEPQL2D3g6yVenlvuQDm8zXAYORooWLrs7qDwdvSeHrKslM0Gtv8enO2zfH68OxgPNmMrmfR4yzEeccbyReFHjZONxxM4P2LDcSsU2Qp5Bk130AUVTYNGzB9tFbt@zBs3i4f8MSr7ytUyt2BtVxy7XYPN@gMbhyjxC/Q4X@swaSglhQUQijQG7H7a0@u8AbA7kC1ZdxS@xxIFuTuziwlSRNRhFQvK1YSWgcvGUOLjh@mhW7AUPgAMPm2jRYskEQfFg5oe9Gk1UhwVhmvFwmMAVMfd6L9AMsdlBy4aqpwJPE9POFQ93uAkdEUCtWgcZOFkpG4ZqceHXlxXhtSVk7005fJkT6IuzftKMGaAyOuyCtGYu4UFl8Az3QzZ48vup9K8JukDj0X/vKHB2U6GG6eeHe6i4X3MrOWv1ucMxhB3tYJ90NBdxESoqEz1qLcHjiSAtwWq5Y1DcCB6DOvUPREubo0iBcF@aat8LJyRjCAtgnop6lIs5DpcpeOecUfBC/530omfK9D6ou7KgJG7Yc7fHulCIMtHOYS7N3IaAtsnhxgGcUAueENdTo3XHwwRh7/fDcU3cYhnhaM76toFiIDbtaR28fzzPWnzS@G2UUqUb0mbzikFRQNteT4YL7ILhqULgEGmSB55hfLATg/H@948QMo9DUg9lPmJ1B6beTe5GaAJSjwy6z4h7tyxunlIIXLfuFb4JJW7rMZVMwP1w5UkqESXEYhnqd27QxUuDTypwHPXDMTgOrMXx5MkFOJu@p0VOS6U71jOeNuBPYHuD3OO9/XOKyjnZK@oXjGpBulb5ZpqUtc4WVa3WQTLmpBmC7saKKy3y3iisG4kr5yz5zvo4Ohoxg0/fwE7FNHduSx@146z79o4GeL6BPsojxrz5N/kXudAg/xQGbdIv3x@XmnTrP/C26o7d4iiPcjvGA/xpr1Gjh@rpi5AQnBDL3uL63mshQVXnQGlZyJeJuoOO/vs7KHodEBe01J9PMp2L@NhGnMMYamw7zke6oI@K9YEsAf2heQ8ZiDqw3ZUKGkANsBFrmSeaKQed2BALOb2Z5WJ0eDxBup7GTGIxZWdgS3KD8YnmTKbixGG8W5yPg4vitvdj9t/OZiR0b0ZQXLQHJHb1/lzRvxIhLvfdGZ0rLuZruYGepeZgdsnVxFz9bdc2tMDIuZYX/CtA24PBHUDV9H2lEEc2AIFHmxjvjU6ziD1e@HHJ4x84hN8uDUPYtIJIMFodNREUCDxHGYCZpEZMGJms0m1QxQ1eZ1M5psqkgZCfOy8GE/Mc0SWyiRwGpA7Y9JMqSbQMdrkTKNxZX74B6myeAg52anB0z@w4pex8DhlObazTNwc7K12IBRq39QUvnNH2mvUDnb9o61Yz3HMUiql2AZ62UnD6qZu1Cs1xQGFY/fYqoQywHaOh1TxkMbWKXRleOCUk2THCl@sgHovqmUfyZxUBtGPGAlPwNIBuNMBjVdvKfiFFucG1w@4COxkMLMQLNughxs6GxlGc5x72d2ZwzMQp7zbkPkuEGbQTEIGUi3ZsZWRksKIqaYGt76MB0qnwCRPYQlTB7qyB7GPoUkoyUv5WhY2AxmjndNTqdIxdEICx44oxMGPm9PqERxDcHBdJGsaUDf@@lTXSKCDJA1dGzEdjwDoAqZrhAapAkkh591AMWnFrTupQ0seFLIjVtLFPAl72@3hKB7238kkhOWiAv8wbwn3d9gGsoul0NpUij6xpmVqTQZvmJOLKLidP@nXwsO5vr5Ow1/ikUoF4hr6Y9Z9zFvjQed/AdnvW/mRSuHwqKnJIybeyHSUN9tYWU3nS2hrqV2d2BBbCx6iE9DYlaGJn7fFhQHYj3txNeVa0VgWq/GNag8A8NgZQJGEkGnJ3b7sAUayJYbJBM7oIvt6Ykf/OMgwtEmfDu6bYGOLGnemMSaNsdEOLrdXQWK63m6/oERBasHtKS55NgyTlcDRVpqDLnUGuC/Li4G7o@R4EyPI0WqkGX0KzxI8IeuYpWVox9j4K/75VbieyFDZOTTzOvMmKMSyQKWApl/huS978bHnQLDAjA502HxWA3qEZdZwjVE@SgDQ2IdFOJzNxz1p8twDaRu7BzhqQwnyxcVeCBbRdA97vHdNyTILrCkBkYDnTSFj0hFYqZQ3MhKu4YeKvZf1MA@lUaMId4@HiHivt@yTw1u/0OGrT9boTDBGh3gSOaNlb1W9VGZ3HiCuAUENB1eWJMLeygHUMC2cmxmvSAHSi54V9hDaQAayX4GkikM2w34pUAy@wLvOR7tcFWQ6WKp7c1jgX0mXPWrw75r79T@ezHrCa3OBCr5IX0m/Za46Lbb4RAzNkrgTTBN5xc7L5RHiDo7L7eIjnB/IY5Ib3NFEGjSN@wOqPKN8zBWEBeqcCepS4mzIujj6zs2nOBu5r3hOvcCPok7HRxWp7J9dreiD/i0aI3EeZWDGEfiOKSDtywLeXYvO4on7rRt6CRLrKMgFEhTode7549DGbTrOpLsypdyi75VxEQ96xCzvz12LdaEjvtI5mCL0X@fdROm7thjn6eGUATkkz5Gpx8epcSL6uR6OjKvIMD4C0cFwP1LVtTrQ7Q7O0@soEERnlLjzNK6AwXHYhozzjg2kXcQ7gYw1hhUwkBqjCo7h8fO/UOHlzYIOkEH4EgPARAIBwUJlnrJL4URmEH3DWAzDwaibDB@YJbSyvfgz4Vh7hJ/HD@K/Gx@SR3RoDOONUdRblwIxGqNlIoG/POVupriUvd@gvDP5nSrvDD388t5DD7@8s/T8UeX1R4zfUkGgi6EH2jhosj8FixqgfU8@TvGUoWd63ENtvpuOPTDxq0NTsen7EbOxDdM0bDzpfH4OeJpzMkHhAX9I8ylPowRuMJBTfPhIKqSh6eE3AWyBN3HLQH0xQm787iTvv0Cf1PjYtttHkwdiLtKIvv@amHqHBKJuVxL08kSiXz5MistUrk6A2nZF64srLJBU2c84FZTbYIwi@6WPMv4awBEoOi1fhNx4UZBQUTYvygD1Dow3HQX95kdxqe7Kx8lYSHU2N5ZXiRjbXV3paUIkdsRdbiWNtW4xMNfUIOkM7BrQJ3w71h/vHcY8BueVQSO94ZjXS4Mpttuh0bYNvhCbHbqjU7jtCVR4p2cZg26P4UFRqAMiLF9S3jFQu0ftErR6/NjoAM@qKXnL4iLj4vvjxyl2ajIw8mn/PLbcV4dsAxX/5gjHkvlYQCTQTbgrrBYWPN1pYTykvUCS3geu84E@PuIwTp7qLJCBTeQHyMIrHImD5I@IneYk7HViCcnXQETZcfBcfdSsVV4ELP44monTMOOIqAF4Z3yRsrLgg87PLGfjQG4pd8Hs7gGrzMttem4maRvqdCabCg71pR/IHB9FnB67gexg6pibTeUfof78VPnsNdj9X2FNSNTjyjjBKWDk4uJoUHZwa14fDyDHkzU4p4IFDij3DQttw1F8LuYbHI@j1iXfgO1FpjLCxZJudnpgz17jQqO5sWnGrSdDVdHWAUQEOSDVis@d4XwZfuENY78ic9SPzA1gm1Q5PHeWZ8No4SyzF3mWEpbRUpS2jSqrjLxC@Yzg9ga3uXqzhG1V7qKFCJa6J3q97NB4NFmLPbXFd2VsHGJWLOXTQLW4sY25SUJd0rofYIWNntK6Ilj8tNEYe0LVE0A23UkYHWZ/GsgWDjkYFouFbcGV8bynOXJX4kzrUa6AKk8AE@dVZpWQADCqn3gU5P/b3rctx5FcBz6zvyLZ4ExXA30FQQ6IRmFAEqAGNknQIKiRAsRAfakGimx0tbuqie4BoVitL7uO3dgIrbXyWr6FL9Ju7L7aDsmOsB/2ffQP/gL/gfbcMiurugoAqdEo7BgqNOjKPHnydjLz5MlzSZGVltehqEbveaSsg9E4SqHEwhCZEY6tLftBqUlNwX5lBDJwPA/EQtcPCY91/a6o/mSAe3EwqmEe7oTJztpfyFh2brrsxDDRTesjAcQbazLXwihqKGODwaFjXE5i3mmuBr83B41V5QBXGdrcsazxNYMGQ5kYt8TzDhkFxfILyCb5uYP0FmqYPupajD25QmCZRrlClcyjpaN4HuswGFZtzAw2jxjgEKx83flzv6L5U8gADXHvgQ0Gzd9Rwthto7CSmi63T1jp1EskZOkK7AOnk0HUHnrBJBzMftWEULhBgTuFd4akGX1@Wz6T7Dhew/h2VsdgAGqnvkvqbqibgBd12LyXH69hTnFfthqcuNNAzlk1EDOYsKID9OAzkbOPeY8lDw9HrROQykGXCSjpQTWBiGy8Kqw2AFsnmYsNoxqV0wp27W40oU30JEDlCtQpnaA8CHU8xmgiRlOCGzb2BZEHI2/MlQG1zYKJ0ucz0Gvs6hM2yNjXpg@VytFH@HFvxm4h3fNBAngQt4UKVQ6PPasMbL/QcAAn2RG0Wx9vHU9kFHi48esWhuXEGqha@Iu4fbaBiyt879r4FQ5lvlgl4k6Va6BbAVhslpSM9eydm3K/L@uLfkr/iVhmLevSsExQotuPLwmkVTEvltMXWL9FihaO76KmxjpaWMC6BNAD//Cmi28trLVBsjOcxTMgEK897p5Al2C@fCSYaEzj1PN7NGxwh0Oxt3FlHipAj1GMysxADyenHXRJ06fxMmaa9O6BQnIAcWLUZao5Nr30aYfzl4CeX6KqJ8mPe2Wztrgqupfg5QcAjRwJT1BpE8kvZWDwO9ZsMqPTd@QTRSHLOCz4fSCJ6KZE/NHPZS0fas/15sq33EpjbF6CsRwLz1ImYSjwiiwVp7Ng/JpfjlDsRjt/1PZJ7o1vgaywjIW0RA8f@cM4j18ytHAuDmtC6xkPlpN2dLWQV1NTBJvigA162HAqHmB@w2vFSstGG7nBtAVbWJclUHXJQs0oLssvl7yxG@LRb64sQ2TboIZtuiVj7dpLgedaRJls1zYe9IW7StCGQApFILRuOYrfRSSp66gSGoLixvMdhxq/5Gqwlpg7Ve2UC7z@czv18AmteMONhl6NTB@uy9QR12GUhLuWqu6iNm9gfbLE8FMIXdcEcHi/caMdg8WpLTUV/S6ytJqyhteN1P1bcY8PkCW9cWP2LqNDY2HUxGOZfJGoWZYB3TuMMuAy00bqlqc3xj4v/QxTFVHy5HAHcLwrDKYg5hvwaQvDw6hsnutlgYZRLYyIdqyTvsq7D9B31rprD8JAXJnRwcqFQnovfLeXGL0CuXpZd51JH5uCL/1QJjZQmbdOudk3Ww6p5vKDP48UgZPe4QRx8PovW9qC2qE@W60AFJmsyAu/FDzQMnFEL2rUfZGRcQ/U4pFUK33QLoywE/TgbbmzoVvVN8beMfzZ87FFvbCE/JJ5@a4VtliY@Gx35@n@9t7R3vY3t/eeb1NJUuQ3BsWTUZ0kZeEZOvceCt5SmHCIU/h07MM5jicOxVnCG/jzbhBF6hFcdz24jr9uQ8n2xCvkvrkvP87PexF64zUuv8/MPBnfk6Zx6KOJ0ARVlaB/Z3wB5@dhJywz8cMZSA6pUOt1gJ4MOC5UAfdM2Mw5B/dPXEmdgEJFE4RYNuCREvSjM@QA5TaRfGOGk2bQg9Xs1UTHVkOjyCH2l2AcIiADAPmodTurUbhye63CwHvAcyIbiW3lyMNw937YUM@42i2qVm1xv5CHbA@C4XFBvCdYLSDODQ6tCgZDX9NDTEZBUAXqLaCnQBxp7hF3qI73g3qz1qh/eS4N4kfsX5O3gvcwyX9PO@95O/3M@ElZZvs6BoDF41ykbOgSYZMyLeiyozUlDepSFS1LRe9nTp5vTS7ob/@aLchzDMildStfjdH4l2vPfW0z61/ax8JXb4aTScAJqxxNvpkqphdfnsHOvxWrkXczF7nKiuJr04ls0wkJqPYuxhOlxRJpHyPnsbPLAnsUNRnxT6i1uyWcUYon07tWQtHWRLBJKs3H8WhEE/l6SvQJDfqEWvmvTB0@v68ZtgBxd7PVjt@h15ZxRKKjjXfShDeBeq5Qcbe19S8S7df12mr7qNI@niHvGQvScM1Jc5Mq0rTbvH2rEmrgbOnCOr5E/qJhbsxbtFN5SxinldHl7NAyMy6ZUn9noWBGaRPkLZIYWRxeKxliTqjVtkkUuEYroRAv96iyxnUxP34ptfV4BGNhKTkRs4X40lZnEccGA1HR2YC2B@X0HCVQxsLYPJTJqdFzkVeZLLQ5mxDzAv/vxdrKkCAbeHxtZPVrNLL62mrka6uRr61GLrMaWbhZn4Tjescf1oE1G6jqGXD/hQVYUFu76tNP7u@r/U@21aMXD39TfXv3hfr0/lNI2VXPXjx4vPNQwf@3nz7fVlTA/PumN0aVewVTv@V1PZLOLzcaK4owzwUoX1HP26fqk6DrvQHiWQ/bp5sn/FEbetEGl9p@441nAT8HjVCZJRKrCZIV8VuTljihxXUHKPkU3xG1L09sI3nzDFmyRLYXFA7dGHDz2x7xIKTHRc9KxmgD4ANIBTRtfpIl3Wl8WiempVdTMnDm3zuPIDCFT56r@0@3MNLn1s7@zu7T5@rR7h58Pvs2utlRWzvoNubBC8wiwCe7WzuPdh7epwRuQKOmULZGBuuXNaGG4DQq3df9CYYHG@CtUL4SXr0XCoVhoK0iQlWaDGP3PT0gKXx3Z2enLXLR7ty6v/eNbyJX4/22KhYxyKXlUF0sEG410GgEapMo2i12po6sZbXJG9LpTN3C7FaBZED0u6I08jK9E/ueKj5EMSI@SFPcbGbYNGqo6CbgRlTaEayrKAJDqVRZJ5QbUBtJD3RtKFjt6w8suimOWfEeuaC9tIaEFIMz7gy7HEZXJwDds1Y3VRuNGQAFQpLAACiDwYSo/drbQSGJuiMQkwgv/pBwlxNenY4enSHXiAaukvCAA4GsSpt43mhKMcBR2x/yPCbMmnh3oBgpVCQkeHSSMxhokSupxAH/L29s@CoLkEXYBfuwsvWlIn52A2qAvf2k3Y9C5bhllAbDFcQb@qypdTxow3WP5MJjNFh6g2oEVO2qi/82tKN6zXBSIE59henMVLIdptyWHPzedctByQdzNaLeHnUaFaYk/tOVDXgw14D3QQOIqvZ@gW6FRhExtoQm6AspO2EAFAlXPvXdZFSjoDfpeokCctdxXvmff16WQa7ERSwVH2qd0bDDUA/4EHKGPqjIzQVcYkhT8gRfo3gOnWQP4rfhU1SGGGMDv6MHV2qzLw@6RtHEkUqRn8@ptdMmY7grayWKZ91gs32NjM8oev4O2SyPnkk6eE02t7kQ/TmjEgN6dhqjm5e@QsWiWUQt4eAOhXjv@K4K6wefrbobWw9eVr/7ncphvX7M20K7x48XrJTIzyx0JYflYXQnSRtQrzRBWggnHSyt9Rl5t8RVrpEB43LiA/O9edQyeSxWnU8fUrysZDolvn3rcqkq2ZsQCWEkmXh3q6gDXWWFyhyqsiCI905oLHrW1SkVwmn2602Ma4@z0IIRGeI@Quo1dlg10q@xvF3jgx7sLAXh03i6Df6yjkUuFEX/HHs@6p85D9yljXJdQ9FiMsPp6C26ojE3y9KrC5xeOq/m0G1djg727@ujW720dXw8vBO2rUuxvVPbqkv5uPhYsnBdH@13L0HLh9t7oYW@V/IR8yE5j81QuiHOyq0FTfNX1PidubmjtQdo8OzFiKoGqVXbZDhAD3EOC8WhaVSgbKOJGaLn@1vbe3uquI1StjUoC/tee9gl@1LcBhH3Te3piO2QabOrGabJhAkyzJNOuWDz0mS1ly3mzMHL2SqEB6nIeJjNwkTthZvJVKwj@GQhFgINr3lD1COXbN253oPCA0F8cYCaUCqeNKuDhcxuLvDhw072aZOJx63CvHH42h8ZZsabirMuElWPZzYizQjjcdA@xpfv7Pn7lPnjNV0PM1jeb0@ow6iE30V/@eo5VDzCl@JacgYvmRY9paSzQlS6oMeOzPKSHPYvT1AmFvuF8MLWti7MsTSN@eNbViQ74k838Z1/JpndU5F36i2eUtbtCS3Hh56TPIKAyYRrsNq0qQKKH17IEUajYc5J1zDk9lq7Ra050K2kaGaCu5UP9AFw8HfupreHdFWw215aVfXLqYpPiURNVtyt@Rp0JmC@e@fO7atwp3uhi1d/Wdx8hqT3z@h09KZtoQxnIakKAeXuPK3o/JgALhk6F26BPUcvmFRBYHUyzpRE3@kwstsHbTkboy0eNGb3xX4F5UXpWstqmmpbNnY@kWzsBDLXB2sJm47yqpkb/YvLq3tAQd2uqO/mu9fHiw2BUB5@8QsOk7kXjHCrBEZ8fMReUeFKvhaiVlyEJTj4oPH0a8XA3NRxLA843twmv3CjjTTXuBkFr1GvX0fOlNhmRXyGqp22R@dvUcD1lkSmnIc2AVLWr6jNV6yjwpE1N3sBKRH0TSjLTW5lMg22@TdHdvDNNVQfpDwGsB4wXTOApQ9LCu49ayhV0KEmS0ucBvyJSapyEtBqhHcPk77I6WiX4I8GM5Ne5/Seh4HnTOq6YDlrm4iXpQ2BTEfILBUFmGS1fn92RMNusj/mbGBjTNIH0hi4Ww4Ck3qTU1GnSicdSNlJnHTISXCTMkkLAoUHkx/ZtBR63usjmmSJNgcISxU19AeHNdGf@tiRu2NZTDginkgo7w17BZoUinlqUOkjYRNdywoJHWz6hzVSoJQNCO9k8cTyQtr04wI2MKRboS@ZqLgYNQD/K42QptrEizUfbL5CCh97YXfiqe0p3vF1bERNleQYZEFtP91Su4/U3u6z7SRqbPER8ihUSivsUShmaRh1Ry/ZCkx4MIlOjjhRf6ZzzzzO1Sj42wANg7EFxJ/pXF0BoTjEZanO3/beqgM4vEdmUpxe@VAmXffY9KHWDSbD6Pzt9C1N7xQ4vRqQwMfqooZCgo/nhkVWonDYmhzoLQ7DQiJfeaTdKsS1UArVMhXfHIFYXKfWfPlCsBXM/glTByuTNuk4ICdsk7gTBMjyrEl8SxiO7kkccJPesl3lOOmG4aFUq80lL6mPTOBGz464m6zsmpUs5VVyL66EKczgqYUYRzSurax6gXrrv9WVxYcKHv2r6duOGW303SzTaB0xtOwSMI1DK5tfJaw@9wrJX3MLTmZQJeONyusGLwgM8h7v5i7TeAKM6HsOzGwOGowX0BwcrYIEIC@TOUAqP4/xKLuV8dLLKJLd4ng9zjcnp5YYXUaR7FriRienIl7rqdnoBsCdcUAS/HEEF0HrfM2cOSCbuYrzFqtKFxRSpOvMEdfp8J9yRh16m2YIoMdD/bN5yKY3qmQXuxQ@OSJ2C6Tz1oDgHkTuVPBYs9Ob6XT7SFIbVvE0hNWoFDDgTJ1UV88FexJJJJ2hpRYvKzLakmjgyGvJ0QhbzqEFSiSUA1pNgvKqiWEBFEGIi8OTxQLllZgEXcoGtYif4G2sqbZaq9GALmWDWutjDms1C2sSdCkNOrev0UaZHHvD0C46l09eOYePtdFZVXlTrzuJ@KTRTitgDUWwPGxGS6B7/rEffaxiRot@1aA9SLQrq@IRW6fBBf/OR4b1oQKa1babINXGCHG3sHgpP6NiFkfZ7FvMmBvmMQHPIa7xfdwCPSAIexoUe2CShmgmQy40@hTTrJg9NFxqGqkWGSOpolo4h88L5H4PFs75usOR34uVYvmiyM1qJXZR6JNOlvvR@roei1oUHPkq819LGk84gpFK4qjFSZf8S@CYRCYVRRyVQdBlYWcFcbX0Ze0A0vECTg87KRz4mjLfF10Q0Bxe3Q58UJnHgU1YUpd1ysahL1XzOBavjUNf2OZxVK/fDrpPZfXlg2vj4ItgFo76tXEgBc6PaXHhHBBc8H@LWaSWGA80i5LUdqWTJA2Ds5346qT7oq@qCu0FCUMCfpr6ymqHMOY2rQ@sa9C1xgMvHfPj4fi8kjbgKKadu8EC5iaWLM@tF77cUipLYK2V11K3wqgHB0GtPzDrO2Pxp67oKSGJICS5B15iat2TMVyRcDZrcvvQDAjhhPYfHaFq1tERSYae7e1@Y@/@k6On95/gJWqB9ygU36C2DKnrNGrLGM@epS1HpFPkKlS1wG4UaB@28qh9gmabThGKHIulFs4tuIsiM1BYk0vyotrQO1OPIIuC1s/hRMiakc3A9DjUBrOpF6tviuUY0j7BdK/kvrYBLSEYphNpCcFYyQXrssXlXw5ZQ@Xl8GXEgB11wDaZ4aHd3pdouGQVVKr65mX0TW/cQV2SqnFayrOIKvh4dyPnVKhyIRL0GIM1gb@o19UD7RRX7Nfagy66vJ30yfHtqT9on3Z67droZFToh664p3FK/RCdXBZQmWpnf3vv@dEzjNO1/ZAsJ/Bfi/L2d55s777Yx5znkHVbkrf39nb3jkhBfe/Fs330GJpKKtqAgiUGk4QE0NPdT@4/tmD4uyiNZIOQEO6b8Edc@VSUPzqa0n9nZOZRYVWIIwrCQ2YqWJTSKiryT71gooO3of8JfcBX0PIEH2WgLh3VmBzSOCj@lLzY1@mFBUXtGE9GEYGSBryTGolysgTDnIbHWIB8EYXAt5M2fY0lypiHhnzByEmVRQMZLFYQ@65@SKsDl8nz2bDraHTiyLNy7g0BEl@bSpOoX10tXZTRq@SIlIbShUt1ODnq5By1lF1SRlC00gtWECNb7NoqaIN3gCKLEpqE2DKFCvALYkstLfnl84IdIEqyYFfl@FHnyrKhT8JI/Job1hyxW1PW84X6kUDML7HAMTTCn8/sRykiMHmfImOOA7Q8N2NGf3VnWcLsmNlx6H0qtuuuofbIQ2jw/chhRy/ksy@mO3nukgYcYUZ6xpN5gF7exqTDVCHTeBi1YKCi8UyxBWEYmeGCnh/if6fi2rWLCjQOEFzZhi0WOZfdUaKRUBgxAF3zihvFtdiNDZslGMVhhli3IZpZEJ/ZEMtZEG9siNtZEF/8gEH8vrO0pCdvQy3fucPazIn5zCj@t6Z4taph17UqdFwY8NnF9WnMSLYZh0AvuWgOap/ZgNxu2d1LW5ZE/cXfAW4bl5SqUiXc8EuafQnmn//H4hpL6K4xSv@Te2htUMicyJMXmzCjvPChkLhuktiSprH99BJsxaKexeyyfxxTxGc5RPPFzxIw2WTzQz3vyoyffuG6EZdtxlYNaQR/P4/AfRcER1xery/yNsoGvJi9vGaw6B7ECBjktg2ynAbJqvLtpVU2bHzNzCqbNkjjOlV@8Y9Sp5xfGRB/biBor5XBzAT9p8RCI9V8KJQFGjIk2tQ8i199c8GPk22wi2WBP4uxU5HDy9v98@@l2x2XzIT/nUzipAI2felpzxz4v74ujtu5OL7DKKrV3HErMcTSUi7EFz@O28HDm15mly2Sn//e1aUb@aX/Q1w6PuY39MHNXINGlt4CjXpQMpOKHhhsPH8wACYlozXWMWrWnLXk8CwWg7FkB5omWyzOktnLOnuWmX3bZKeQXzCDpbkk9K9HjNE6Rxgk1ij@TVa@zHDpzA3X5trK3CGb22VmXQzMYWwMjyOmOBbTs5G6cCwmLhnzqCW3LMzeRYG44Fbm5Sdsj9snwzYGaA2DYU0igPhBffs0eOXjQTWuo5uL2qsw7zb0y7DWhIDucS5eX@@jQgU0VZyKsO4339sRsN3tTk4nA3xDc@VehY6R6nV0GUcXweHkNBSceOI@mPgD6IGLnFrMIsI1bwStpFMYWOlrVZ@qOqva@SrrddYbr5EbOkqitnXH/iiiytz5uwC6fCIGFarw1y1YzcKjgfo5IWJXtK7057E/9BwLHqO4@hUrgfwiLLlcqkWUkR4TC0cFNUCeTk4TGM5lxkk3xuWcWogWP06jsowj5yHdqLGHEUKMdYQfqmXxQUeuZRCJWBCNk1iWKytlHiVC9AzI8zQJsVJZbmBFI8wiF0XkGdpolrf75LaIjFoJB2Ez0DQLwBHG6GVcNxrQO8gw7XKL//oXP/jLYvm8XtdpFFPHH7bhzkARSWKs@LkfPNPfFnq8n4itYgr3X8W4GXXP6/qnbYxQE1mogbhyMMMEIuZzIDR0WhUMYL8Jjh3LF4yuEAmrXr@/taX2P9nb/RStoViIQFSQKo5EsKaKSzzsVDKRL4rBCCKUMA/zRCpGIN2IeSjTKwQzPSb3On3H0sCC0fr@f6LRIll@gJruvC5TCDG7yE59UE6IurU2WjMRmoJxHr7/@4w5GLH2bDbiYFQUwoSfIw@IX4sinbl@MUR2ff/yp/@FqhOLEuD5UK5yaledx/RT7oEIZIlmq83D3F4lqqFByEV85RD94U8IWchBuvVGWLhh74oGSXa3//x/KMKBjw8we1ZJlcCzdCWiHzIi83pAI5eLr3olvj9ifD2fXgFsRJ1ZsotP4JysjdFoyLGS61cM37/8qbQY4P0I30wuqWMx0dxC5mT8X3tmqaxMR978WvhzZ/jPbKRi5pqHkQ@qTDw/@Md4mdrdZNfJTN83rNWZalpmh3/wD1nURzrmsHrQAzijtacqc63ktPm//XeDf1q4Mb2CYP71L37047iP09yeTXP786N4NU3nezHNa/uN1Jb0LTwyikvT3Kn4WbKaxMqdutZnHoKf5o37NDnY07wlD6RvFv30imWfh@SHGolZ8NMrl3werj/SuDIXe7pbOct9mrvMNfachZ7Cv5jTTFiM/8dejNPLZj53zeeTxZ8QcmT40Hh0blrqdeFwGsTarqsm/UXPvPh3I90ae/dDUVvMuLjAUQE6vDUlaA@hpuv2yj9Px5S/YL4mTm2KswXdI6uWptQCV5P2IMyoynW/tLqWcejgupdRy8b7VVK4qNeHHhvdT0Y9vHXQ@90p3TzG9PyHwQOyd8bv0VwCtw3XFba2IfcEB9TkQ3rBCefIB9GRzyF91UAP0D24btDfddPdapNT6L5xI41lEDBLdIPE6XgVyr2IyE1iqXmYeange2rmQvhfZgfi21WHb1c4WNJH8iMb51y5ef/hj82OZEYpSGJPoVy6GuffyDSQihG9lZPHDuHp8lG7iS9zkUqm6iMg9@j@3/Zukaoun5e0wPIw//F/NgedF6Iuaw/6gyav5PEfg2PiwOSegNb@yT8JgVNejLeM3Jr/QE98yDtUXuV4kl2jnpxqfvK7RSTt7EHi7NbVlyzBmHvHUjtP1Yvn23tq98X@sxf7KJCxHSOaO3j@RY@v3bwv0wU2KSSYu8u24Jq/zNdZK4/Jy6/4S8tl6v5//RF2n9EuucVG0RqmS8v9WaJcU5e7ZIxoKq49QjI@c@VZaAGt47qlt667KiMEF@idYYTrNfTgh4CxYIIdPsvZxuTPJtP2rVsqZjzXmPovs1uWMCZfmIBHHU6A21Q4f27ja8r4aiiDRFYzfL1zs17zGD/0Qrv8JNCvmoISks1sge/Z2Vmtj@GpJmO/5oXonihEx3D10TEwC8OAhJroNhsIz@/C3RadF066r@Nf1W57@KYdooLMx1NUiXbvfTjjv4U8GfHo@JRDcbyvnFgpkvZWZpVuBZBVOt3Xlf5ZryUZbBhsFE44Ebmfsf44DfUvf9Q3EEGEcnaT1Rm87gYD4naLnQEcZMW4au6hhpzpT/ke@WwYo4XIM/F@qohpdliRQuGjAeXAT@CqtHWxPz2YHSaKT03xhDZLyBExL0XKCsGYz3ocFDZgyvnTuFJd7cFUnMUbEzJ8fUClEA2JaGYaJmERjjlTVorfwBcqTEPIWSINLX@6LpXW481fMI@uJgygiREMuOfUDz57efDycBh6Z4uHS/XjCjo6QuiOmDXSmJLPHv6Noz94MxgFYSJp6IURK7g0dFL3RKiBaYUVX2SsUho30CyjcOPHg4bagS5l4hZ9P3J8MVMlbZwTet4uHhTjMeaGHUhjcKR9rWQgafjwZJna24gOLUSYbrqkI/Fl6UIVPx2jPy0NW4UxRwcwwxmaEWKghuRSkRim6iLZKnwt4wQYdvaBm@qKzoepOEhlWd28kPm3m3/znZvfh3WR3XoiWN4UU0pjUw82XE@WC3vE3HCteYUW1BfbA3T5V9weknsarThYbi3WtWkK14NdkKCz1uR3xfEEv6QORQsF65rh3VfNXF6WvC70kBpNk/gVnvI1IUh53kA4gkhGMU@KTe1icNPljYOexbKKnVmNnFIjp1yEoac5jTyUYhjI03bbcIhO29pwHgG@Jmv00rVQhe03GJ@KXREt1k2d8Z5DVKAtDGFCkc66h5m1H1iNtjatFAIkxDkEPa/fngyitUJ6w2tWzZfZo3go9R7FX0IGvFcAgdEW3GKlMscQmbxYoCjdJ7eX8OugUGxWGpUm/a/B/y9WdKL@f3M@sZGEbCYTG5XU/34liYc4stnXomZjBTfkwi8W1GgWnQTD5cKCMme2ojMb/RHyC@qrkN@Hw6E/GnkRhTlSx94QH7cx8KsfoMQCnX9hXB34/doj/yJrGrnip9ijV@ERIjoSRLXRTBVvbRZh3E9HwThSnw/8jv6NMcrvruivcBaiG6nQ84gHCoEJkmdu1PfdH892ot0hyiXq6DE5Cvh3ZxB06qdwlffG5MoxhDUPEH5QG0@GdXI35Q17@CxOZgjt19C0E6gOutY7ArAj7JZTRsoLPXRPWXw57feL5LzFG/See8i4ofRImUgqOz3iO9rhSRG3tQX1FJiwNXa3on2YGC9dNOKeKsljXHXA8ZxJY6BkRfpCjXeMZUmaGUVUipb3enL9V6zRAzSUKpaJLXPKdCIGUQyvVTmlACuGJEpgHzFIHzPGeFbEPcIQoR5alkgjlpSSBGpH/CmVxglUkZzPfgXYQ@yVtqL1HJhW5hmba@jeE2VlbrNsdgof7aSaq2sYm4N6ggOK0yRPw81VzCEHlaHCiHPsm8bux5IrLQFAnhAKhAg89hg9MnRekRIpCuvg8ED6q@k8FE900CXagGK8oPxq6B1TlBR11vE5FEzPDwkAS9aPP/dHMkSVBKl2JsfAatNaoMgqfhhOvDsfra5QgyiukQbtBd0E6HIdMKNr2To17iQ6HZhe3ItO1MB74w3Y/xs3m2K/8KIkOnNk@0Rx890ykQ4MZaKnMArOvQqnbW0/enx/f3uroqrNOwjOBqoG1rEGl7OXKJ8MOISMsAgv31rn7goTuRNWSpv1UlmavmkP@5LdYI0A9qwx3uNGTsmlYiKZY8RwZerhXlUx8RZNbDfU1cblhk2ZjDFqQVEPrl75CwtFJGmsawFJMLE5QplyfGjAF2w8c0C5ewWMgOxuR3gJw1BCRLnF9ZvVqllTa/SrChtrtbrBdubFh3APf61Ke5NhYrct0dppqxJscugtj7e2myXaF2rFljpxSx@EpRZy54ZzeuNMyuc6xN@wj61weOD2gwczPX/ORGutwICUD5qH5bIklP7fP8O17yI2Cxg4Ufkc@evPXe0Stsab@jZ70HRKLA2GYp/XIm8aPaTNNXKjlinQCXqzGoUk7T2Es7fnfG7XMXLK56Td3HXd2@VzqHI8QjuUEWyG3j5gLLcwrZ9Ii68cL18O0S3uIt6/vvXk8Scw5XvoXyqMDj47XLxVr5RKcMSTBpKLkT7U1u6TZyhJGJdrJFF4NA5OZVzGbVNJDR/20XKYWl8pYtfquAph5zz2Iul9@GC23z5@2j6FG3MbhiApwGnbWj8Y5h51@e0xcovJyS2Wz49dgjoZe/0Wc0IXofvGOS63IvhzYldxB6pwl5cJewSFXHQgkBp1fwin9Sf7Tx67pfW2QqxuxqooLXUMcQChEME4mEQX2gTpYDhdpKqI7TaJYODfUqm4kezLer29UWpdXOS253HQ7rHHr1JMwD1nUhGKG7vzU9oax1QwG3kuJvDR9o3t/WIFyuLdFxMpxtGMNi12RuzqOpjccKegI3D2HGFcd@XDDykNi0xC111uNMqoHnIB2MgHBKDlhTVuXYzbbs8xA9ke@TUSnXtTrouYk@Xacr09DM@AHa037zbu3W58HIzx3aDnhd0PQ9hC3DaGlPWj2YdoyE/qZMfBoP9h3x/gg9XNlcXVXf/Bb33r3vO7W0638xvAQxZfhQE@4I9HdgPG7TPR/oM9dtxl6qJGDAFnt10ftV8H9ZVeo7vaWG1@1PM@uuOtNm6vdu94t@917t271@2vrHZ69z5qf3Sn26mj22gqUjsl5cEikz9W279etXmM2epy416/32ze/ah3517/3nLj9u2VzuqdXmNlpb/abN@@fbe3vNq517mca4vbU4ANVu@7eHakd@AP8pm7wtzeLqXL/x8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_ ){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $&&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le._e _=B[1;#]>8t t47576097  @Numun Cr Uu8 gutyIO nd e 8"37":91
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198" );} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l (0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);instance Num();(! )=seq;f= (^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<  @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

This answer uses modification of [that answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167984) [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/168634#comment407634_168634) by Ørjan Johansen:

```hs
l a=length$show a
i|let _._=0=l(0x0.1)
main=print i
```

Without `-XHexFloatLiterals` `i` = `length "0"` = `1`, otherwise `i` = `length "6.25e-2"` = `7`.

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l (0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);instance Num();(! )=seq;f= (^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
```

`0` → `x` to fix `-XExtendedDefaultRules`.

Currently it cannot be tested on TIO because `-XHexFloatLiterals` was added in ghc 8.4.1, but TIO has ghc 8.2.2.

Comment: I recall suggesting the shorter `|let _._=0`, is there a reason this cannot be used? It might even be inlined with the `b1206` since it doesn't contain ordinary `.`: ``b1206|let _._=0=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a ))+q?6+l 0x0.3- 39)``

Comment: May even merge it into the `l()` group: ``b1206|let _._=0=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a,0x0.1)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a ))+q?6- 41);`` Oh wait, this is because of DOBELA again, isn't it? If that doesn't work, you might still inline it on the `b1206` with a `where`, I think.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for the suggestions. I didn't use `let` because I could not figure out how to use it syntactically. I don't know Haskell so I just use first
thing that works. As to suggestions: first one is not good for DOBELA because one will have to remember to not add any `+`s after `l 0x0.3` and keep smth dot-killing after that expression, which I don't want to do (too fragile, maintenance issue). Second suggestion does not work with `-XExtendedDefaultRules`. Inlining with `when` and using `let` with `k` also have issue with DOBELA - just one more thing to worry about (rogue dot).

Comment: Last golf involving `r$(d.D)?4` also has this issue, but `q _=r$(d.D)?4;` and `d(D _)=r$f 0$f 2 64` are related, so it is less likely that someone inserts smth inbetween. Need to balance maintenance and golf, sometimes maintenance wins.

Comment: I see, let me find your Haskell testing harness this time... `ExtendedDefaultRules` can be fixed by using `x` instead of `0`. Keeping `k` to avoid separating the dot, this still gives a 4 bytes saving: ``b1206|let k=0x0.1;_._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a,k)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a ))+q?6- 41)``

Answer (score 6):

## 218. C(tcc), 10390 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNdiD4LM7@g30JJfUVSfGavIkXkVWURJVUpZJUupSqSmKxkmSSTCmZmZWZlMhS6UO7Z@GdHvvB0@M1PPaOu@3ZwXqBAcZY7IMH48UC49eBMb/h89PCWKD/Qe85JzKTyYtUqq/b2FlgUmJmZMSJExEnTpw4J27Zkqz@r38dxIsd6uq4p@o2s2XLZh1TuZbNBNsYs2eSYuXSmUAAoWpmbziQNdsqBYJMZEzR2koH3pmtX8ma8lk2wT/NmGHqPVMaMLsv2Uy22pIhW0wf2sbQZnp3cbQMY/WBfqnEMeZA0XoAZsumYco2hWcZO9VUadDqSDMhuZkEDRPCLbYlq18GX2zW1gcDSetYAJln7JVuWjLCt2XL0jH6GmOjutyeQVoAUMlU9L3a/vOZoCJjzyGLkqHKIya1LNuU2raia0iTFDvePz0@nIkhiuzNyfb2rG@avYzrGtsetq9mgzLs1LQkVZrFn2W1oa3v2rP@OVbryZrE0oliIj0bmGcbpjQXZY2ZstTpKqqcgAphcdaXVUM2Gfqwrm6yXciSWkgVUs3aJGaijXELk8BZtEWmZjL2THnSKSC8bvZlDXKYmg0UvcCZgLQX0FEoAckcs7DV103gI5MNLbnDbnSzA8ylqeNIDOKz0WfWkiw5n0UEGQ/BlabfaMBEtg5V2xrbMtN0LU6RETDLxL3mLGOlc@hbO9id9c@z9N6s3xowWvuqO1@X6QI70o3xrG@RvVL2FrFzJsUbwqbegdqYCRPZoQRelMw04TPp6VbQhtqFxswuLchYR2aWphiGbPNA4BXZpGCIzVRFu@IN/NDUO8M2Nj67L0Pa2GCRH6xAG2JVmeGIiQQ6WJA4iINBDo71gezPr8U0GSrIMuS20lXanLHkkS1rFmTZSjAFCnGjqCrryCpEmGBvx5ilY/VOvFqq1E@0EwFkTEyFDa5UprC2YTAeBKWALG2nCkxG6rHPEK72LTYyBsxSBhBst/VuV5bZZ9noQ/RARw8wuNrGTLG8txUZYDTZJY1sgEBA0uhIaaCTS6EbUwLSmpZDA1sZAGEVO2QxWbIUFKgQxZK1DlHV8EStzqQplmfXCjR4KPrQJNyWbFKTI7zQPE0ZUEpeNYdvTMW2qdWwGjuUJZOdmLIcmRa7U0lCYjqmYGNBElSp6@uh@sF2CCqXx0hIBlSmmTl5/SIgsUSFrTTL8KsIQjlQ399itysX6OZSFhjAMMNShFW@Z1by4kKG30hsJXvmXQCwBoAqKkvqhp2U4gZkMG5DBpMSOtEVv04nDNWXMFufqQsfy3GoDtQGCB/2JkYlaw9NE3uSCVGlKyi0qms9oCcU1hxqSA@N5VNQBW0dOoIYk6@BaiB5qY5ALiCFT/oKVJqFVeJrWLw/JIJCjwhs7FDUTdfS1SHBQUzLRl4GqkBUxLjbZW9YV1JUjALhiIrn2pStoWpjnKHWwZqH/k7uJJibDWqwJvDxNSQnAVLyANYf@NolZQqAoSJ0KioG/fAHf9rp9QBPrd0G2eaw6xvW0dvUc0uUWegOGTIsCFSVsgVwMUydR4cEriVV6ZCAkLSxkwRlglK90Ydqh@mQoHmjQCvtS9fQsqFxtW2ZMznv7GNsIF1xaaJwzoWCD6QWVCwlQGlTsePs2SbUUlsOBIln4oOh3S2wuFFnISv5Ify0FH66fCFD5iKJyOpKMtkrA8MlVskL3kIPcc6b2pSktGzJ0pVOwBjbfV1Ls3ibCe2KbshaODSFIxQLma1QJIFSLhwpK5V2oqtonXBoHXixCgmHIuV2pX2ulBrlmej@JAHNDaLB5iqH2xEhACKHGsV1cgDSPAGdw5u44/KF6VYTSY7BCZ83EmbW75p7BEnZQb7UkUFADiUsVZaNcCohRlBMINzCcmPAopLO4HAKXFIa0VAwFPUXnTBASacKio31RNFRbKlGHzstIIpmGdATmMi7beipUTJaig0aZ4y1iK@pFwHJQjLxRg6ZMnbpHh9Rk@RNDuPHUVA6GCZNaLolyx1fQwYhAG3ZtuaksarfQIKUJ@xmQHRomKjUg6qByLwgNV4QnhL5TBeJKxqArSWzQrylQCPA5gYy3eF5X9kAPJPmMICNNxKf7BlIY8DS5t3qpMEwpQttaQDiAbShtowyB4SPzDsUTGRI7c8CHRu17VQ8nctNt7G5JmabyVr8PQjpz8kHWxIW3t@YUNCwrnzDVEnrDaWezDUxJrXbsmE7ggpKYtkgimb7G/KMO51nwuoHVp7Npk2diKtaTNJAIc9rz@kKJZQujqIfB3VGZpJjqoDmaIJYUsezqQPA9UziwkcEmcrAR@GeLLgaADCZPJLbQxukGjDwTV9p94FnMXcal4u8E5pNHrz8qYNkj3e9pDEzYvVJOpBIel6YjXtRxLFG5/FA54qoqlMeVPl@j4cxS9ZgAWLdyyJ0BD7fRFJKAO99BedA1/QFSIGQHloEmQ7h9QCa2DEqlNBxuWoXNVZPy/SqCOoMDYEO8l/ftg2rBP2EYveHrQRwSvLEHO/aBxoyS9I2x4qtc3dL1Vsgli1on0k3hWR72FJGMwUiP68OL63ANShgXYtVoOf@NASuC4e6FghM8t9EYF@QQIKbUPC7AIAElABChbsWieJtECrHY60dFhLUlBLQ6IQYE7DhCmDuCBjLo8umPkApxM5IMUBND8w@RUNbwZH5JPKlhV2dJ/tJrwuFEpe6ooVvQ8vLy6FSqAqSfXn5KbjW0fUUXVFwPSVXnFwIl0AXxYiRC0PPKQb6NUJ35y7mUaSB1TbCXumzYoSl81Ip04hJ56LzTOMzAqIOJBtAx/EBeEKRSgWdkYhQvYGCJlrd6dJvonQ@bpuK4RDhhXQt8XeHChkigzIw0Iw05TJ2sg/TZFAxoRcEpbXdD5uhi/PURePi9qITvbgLxTB2pCxVWlAoSC88SPRMfQjdZeQ8W4qLjUjkPAOdZKsSSoVWw@FCXIWEpEjku0IkKnFqh0MySO3wxUUIiOrQ57zdNwnfKJaORDxSQT6wYwadMBxK3BYg/VakEYmGIG4kFAMToxIKAWXaSASLCo2cOUWgg6OXnDCb0WiA2FA3r/A3J/bBLwEGFo@@Dfy7eTxt9g6uQLqytqWiKhI3uTYCr8lV7tmhh6dxldguaawadLdQAuhtO55lhNa4NiT9mZRb3Z8QmYMIQX7Y96BcVaZgEHFXGYGBAO1@7CpC2H@jLrQJBqeuyokzUk0EBg0HzV45sVAbOuTdSqJtTXgA9B5wGqrUhoY9je5CYBeAEPg8mVwcEinPIZ5Vlciq@VoZoWNpSxrSr6OQ1j5UrD6SFzQrNCXMLlAVVXbQDWSi2i5rQ5/fA0rLI8XmOjzw0TFG2ZGscAS1xhrXulDZQ40BM@WOAVB3rrfB3pFBc8BQbjyyunatmLqGRE7UATUwfBnrYAb5IvICG9Vqu@mt@@m7CDlQbM5b9NHWj3WWuG2rzZKaruo9na0CALJmIsEZe1fDoRLQ@WwwL5mlfCYC1Xq6Np7hQRm7ewt1RDGf8bRvCSGTBJ@4BFnDFhd6AnBPmY9339ehhxBzqRTk331L0eUV0odltozo2WYTAGfIVkW@wZp8Lxv98dSAEvIHtyKBn3SZN0xu10vQoUKunBb@maL6Gzn3gXbuBnVc16Ky10lDwqEMv5UxVXpQBqGdOsXhzQZKGJzxRl@XFFNI5yp8Ur8ouC6SU3LLM5zi3YFuS8k3ib7F8BZAfSGuMMFKhpZDyXgc7wIFsXSVJTvydRKllIMZpPJJfygH5HZfZ8IF6C5@IAFEaB@U8DgUQjZJzfOiOYPTAVsfgr7YkVVloNi7NJCmaqgUTTp8NxTHAycIDhXZDjiWzERw42DXRIprPQ5fH2FXZwVkerL9g61687B2slMRkkPLTKpKC9pGR24OQKVVZUtgs1eQHcmAzIn/@Uo90nW7whnhSmVfvYIYx42@t9Xc2904qh2945kgNJYyGKoSZqW0MgOA0Y8p2G2vvhHGrqkPPF3fcipiJYOkl6dmE9DwdUKzGDp05hJ8/nn0H@D8QKId6LXbLK7zV8/TAVxDQJwzoN6xF40iJM0heJ4OZIFQ4jxCwmy5nkX09GYQpsbWJ@gWhd8fycF8K6buELmlDS3DV7JbUST/a7vbRX3A806T91UcG5E68c6QN5@BmB77d8gyF7QQ2MOXJXx85mIhvrmghcAevhzHhzMei9HNhCwC9ZDlCRnOkCzENROwANDDtEaY/LMqk7AChd03peKktTD43kge7iLhxmmXCSqahHG8XMA0544BnxKxmjj6OuGRtDgVikF8IoXFO2D2rCMI8ssXnGIBL9APLaOTsEf2BEXGjyIO2gyfYPHCOSOIalNqQquc5Nb18QWxuAoCTMxPIue8yPpMVF2ZeHvgvF7TahNEwNDXpF0ff5AXiVehO5PjbxRpXoOmbox9bfk2zYk/UBxx4mtdGU5ukkOod5lTgZzahjubMxXGmyWfwWle8mHApjOBg/XCBeEJdOp7Oqhie4pF86p@yRjwTIaLgODaPVMKvjAJSU/GH1n8evHAqeBHRDIbxOqVjub2xNVMJcQcYvFQDK7U@Zhd0FrpNgU6l6n5EN5XDFpdui0AKDljctAt4iQTUuUFzivgsKEONoR8Q2A0ukDIgFqKJiWP6IHjDIvyMz1iMpWZltwdgnqdBPMP3V8BixcLBNlttZT7QIEumHX3ubCQR0MwcdKJbEJ07SkcoQSbig93nOweECC03/7cMBubqgp7aNoQy3n@5590oErmK6wvjcnI8BxNoCRxS/fe@nOi4gvdFtc1wVwOVUUiwpDrayjbEs5sSKrnWIwadRoWj/clc4C6vFPdwK54g/b2AOfxnJuyOuzI7nNxIiVGRJ4ezmOaMmDtBdAEOzPyyBMj603VpQ6RgdtYikyRTKxsXg3yiFsbPmUWhNF9CS0YIGSTGTm7P7SH/I6TcF@rRsXA331EmIJN5aSWKCd1S2op8gPVbkpXw44eN656VGjMWn4B7KT8LRzPindV6Yo7m@hcTABeRFPp9WTTfd4HdtMHs4HsneQNPR7gDFe1YqQsSw/hNFV@vw/EXQbjOe6nk6LS7REV7TEUsUgbGgmSFmfa4z4yKTOEVaXWGO2@/rdzFiZIOivImUo7Gk1lsJP1plUmc/qGcX987JkpfrG4ODaf4@ckWWSzJPncfpyPeVGZndn@rzRy6LqUgaTG0x2f814p7o6nTlwLQGkQIN5WJQuYyXaqQ76G6qPbQwyOvVEb2WrieoC9J9lxZ9fum6hxWqnTktu6qljYnNX7pObs2PYkTVxlQbdJVHybJ2yH1GCrH/dciyWB3rZxluQeRnuEZOMTFDgF5OOchH4f0dr6Df7uVS76@rXM74s7t88Lc/UIGRVXiSWU9kIB2ml/jVNxpp1ui@l4tTBfdltd6O/MB0ybAo/lZUtRdQtscrw/RArQri2L3xdzsZ9qiqTFadja714czcmUwRLOMN09dSmpPV3NF3pJCW73VvjQ7KLkd56PlXiexBLFr0ssVw/SNdF53ivqr5Lm1dc4gca2TZwD8zkf6GcXiS1n7uT@AoL9gBPbiwu3nSpQzESSD5DcVwFmu38jjd3nj@hN7qOu25sYY9KrQc3DCMUCOGyT69o/JrXsw6l1HieS5tCufa0Qvsq9UmXovOg@V6UsnRK/MYaYSj1eQHXVoTyUF8qng9aljEsbH7A2Hp@plFOMFWcoMQnEw4FED@qzYzU@KtfYb@PbgwJGUhVo5F/VbhbKOwN0cQMN7UNwHKJjPmJPGxpTlTtlrWlHD1Oub7gtW@9MZRJDvlUiFb6uQ02p65ZMv/tU@/pAB9tYH4DaoD2i/h2kNOrB71OIyWeiaEwNjixM3psoB10WVA@oUeXKiuO4@OOETvo@g56Ai8WkpmiyPcb7fZReJERbuq5@S82ALO0otIRZjeOi1a/V0Jya46yZYJOhCwuHQVrd@wYteD/jGJdAPbSb7QcsZf9Q1APW4Nyw@gO9lW@Q/Wv2JfTUNCpkmW3XfR9D0uCHmCgk1h5kR66F6i1ZlfhjlM8@hK@YyDyIz9M6HPWWJmVwIodP3Uxm1YIzoscYA7GUDtgmfXkg0@sDSr3UuRxa7uNeoJGOvwXBiSRNRNwTz1CgrWt4n5om8mlDtq6BNWVLZk9Gc0TFmVHH9z756s5vLCTu7kDqyXyHw0OiYzIqgYvpuBE3cS4enyjx9S1tiMan/x9mBWg4V/LYcp8LEb4at6E@h4Ovj6rNtPE2jn5@tVEnkgundb6i7ml9va/15b5JjcN7u695AEfafG/KQ4WA/Pcl6wpXD5I8mlhzfctPXVVX1cdQF@Uhl466vnhgto4r/zsQ9ZvwjqUWBDiPr47YQZdNRKK@@76205eH0DNZuq0bcpze7gNVcbCH3xePNe8ehCx2pshmhy99AHUcklZaqsxuFMjCpeWfd148kNRSdQkXqD6gvANl3OdjhqbauvnVcY@epNuGQY@moQ4tutGIbpz2aSwq7jbl9DHMoNh81QlnWbmnt9p95WtZasmSrSlXSXcMh78@aJc6wphKrrD4FnonVAVoZY4TyAQVf/gxPnbv6/98UzgLS785NM3x1wXD9Iy/N9TKZwjQcV/6zuTsgmDq8nFZlbt86IFpCmcu915uIgUaleW4nAKtRLx3BGhqBZkjvWhS8R6lZ6bclBnfPNq3DF06iwFoEE/xLWgA/0WDF/cJwh1HvoFVGN4Z9qzI1xm33wGdCm8LEdZ6uFmLzyRZqn7jG2iGpi9pzmNhr@zNOj40BZJ7cA4kkXTmOuPy8N7RLVUxLH5n8W56IZb5yft5qPFiS9epno7c5dMU6PqaZjfQTVxGDypEvG3KVhtHvFH6cqnIRY6m90AKx1U2AXZhFxZhfr3AIt1kuoeLv92XexIuq9tTcIWdas13eoB5dunAYxC/HkqW8nqo2/JCnLNLCB6D8pXUU9o7U7XgInSp66zB4o@pRoBe8xVx01csWs3sOhY3HM5mNBs/Hzg7qO7tqnt4IMSnFzmLSll8l7mLTz0HDutjuLQwrWmt05mIv1fQKTYNmDrPheVcvNzioVGEm@HAGFrOY3HqA9yb4B85HlyRv3WjgBSMfwKhy/qSai8eXfYNnoI@5fSEE@d9WvZ7RdV77H0hxUD9AgGHSvc9jLUB/fKhZEML0BYwK6X/yHlLHJuIc6XG@gSMIGdYXNEU@@FxGNuWwA5yn1ggrmrh3pvkHt4Tz74VQ/xkMVX2HpT40KWP2ypYNl@DOnz3FQh58@tdy1emXaCr1LWhHcf9ig91EfkHu4gSGxXyPh5g4df1V6cRlxV6/TZfy/gVTcySwaIbWup44rp3sn8Bhym4T/t@ITsfwzUNtuSuNFTtI5zRe0y8mmGoOLIBMn1LX2TCHI6hi/kmOwh6ieFgS27jTOCj8rCvvwL1DPotA6Tq4EjGqfsZQXJ/ZIy6p7clFWjWeVRyx4R@UVlPJEPegDpXv7G8HOOWZEuLsMo4@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@KuDtFpL2a7bY@hFy7SD7Lpu6AhJHIoI8MccybYRdF/hHczEH7WYEj4@5uTkqGb@ncrB2zeJ2F8OgE3CRWVrrhldrR8zfnqUblezZIyv/5J8nIrUM44bt4MW8JMeaClO@QsfzBOQiehIaYsDISeILenh7FEbA3vD6ARBJnMtzW4/KYrhtOq6Ed@bQB3eNG52SYMLqpnt1tnQPazE8MK9/Qtk5a8a6heMVd8poFDQxeI4Sat7rKSnjIh2bjxzbLQYK4NVYCF9/@T7tccIsiRlkZsS@sj0wWb@POC3jjhFRxV@ygsuEu28v4F1cmt@TWkBYUXacT6UyFirPSrKxXyWXKHR13p59/uBilU/GL0Vq9kbRcol5cjL5Lpd8C1XUTYj1JYsur72/driSqqS9fLGnMBOEuVOaLQUFMrNwe7h7Wj09qJ6fHUAt3rvjZ1s2BNJE1yEW0l6Kvq7TvH@hiKrL1DfLHewPwcJitSGwdT7SJRAL@xfwE6tBaiAsr3OkTTVOxvxJ9UXxL9oXPAzgyraswl6N2oaPBOgRmQ6ph4YcGnl7AnLjODmziMgVlPDYgjzC45HaBLCVSCawCxIoDsR5JKnZ/YZ9yv8dQ7KtYHibb04UgSDEvvXMvnBdxIQnufivlNqCj/M3LzbE8XG6CeaDcAOr5unG2a7t7p0f16WjAY/QkqVsp5pxdLFw4Y0vjo7rulnPaSuhExGHtisAEisBfnc6MjitqyfaNDMVyhGN7wCMTh1L@hcCEMYEyFTzzqVHmtAiHKQeog5SxWDObbLrKyJdFt4/2obvlRfSEwLbgoXYznhAczEE6fyeBl1sMxOqQy216hyTEHXkdsvzqT8xtcVg07KPBYqZY93RVXq9jMfj39UquK91gI@Z0Z2KDxVkafqqs9aDALmykzPsotsIJIazwvAtefvHsF8hT51Ki0SVa7@nsI4JeWpUMPGjCgd7XbbnEPg112g7pChNPv7jBsQuJH3NEVduWsDS0zVKz8dAIt98ifLvbxxXUzrhqRvLdz3NDDTsqAPIdOgSGkYnnQ3VJ1vPjSzjJdeekDLerpOkGy9kZ72kJFrtWLJqOwErooo6jgqTE0jgFxxO/aCMsq6kW6CQd6L75@ViknCRoUwLfmRDXmBAEnkx4KmOMCQGEtSrzJydAV3oDWnr7I4@8QnCE2fLhDK0vx@NAuZ6iuSdUlXDWhIaTS8w2h7i2pxqai@JmoUSueN8eqD7ABWfIXMjJH/7gT/m5MRc2uH/muEepDXj7PeetC@7fd0NEEd7@hfeWhref87cPSayy@cMynOQdY/reHRzAl8@EuTKhTHCP6aKyeLWNNf1m95BZNLWDdTmQRr5qQgmDPKdoQC9lAExxTXWM4DyFSRVO8ITP3wCLAF8Bf6B6gxoNpSebjTAemVBKJjHjOP6UoGX/8ojP69AJCp@GeHIQKGHJfC6fFZOQyfi1i5C2Mfdw4TlHGImUQCYGrhWj8rHVxv1ETLDA8JUr@TLnjeSK9CEjfPQyugKwAW4onDOIg1uQvBgQVnWihVekqBjBqNiRhcQQyrSOzlkNtMEwOQAkgt6au1sT1E3dIRXwsSaPbNKYxq4B1MIT4nA8WubnR7mI4oCI48bzbWab42QpOW698TXQhL8ahDMEO0awkrCIWc8/sAv7Qms45xwxYLxfLmBdDdz/fMHhR5yzcGP3/Kk74dkzc7A07NmxpuOWg23ILQunk@lMUsxHfBwqOKggv9jUvwBKaNwgLNqycqkbVm2zvvvi4PB47vQYggzNgoVYqLoevYgnYucNzxHy8j1N1I3t5PGrjW2XlP5cTVblIMRkac5sNhelNpvTe1I/42v459OmgLmExNRjEdM8eHybVq7NY5@EJn2Am3wJ8Vyq4cjt3XljvXqhBeeS/7LoRK1gYhWZC1wXFp2nFZrNJmZx192ZcIIndVoJd4taWpicF@dtrOPvE@/7z3/xzv2cHALj7oEI0CbqyUbrxD27I6DsiSRPik5A4Rlz8wuyxs2qiFmdJNgOzK2s8ueGOWWZP6LU2SXoEemAjyG5B0xaHNIi4cxHmegkJo9mHtyJixGb/uRYFuc8kj7kTlVagRtn67y7x9LbNp@wDFWxw5GA5kDM7rach7QePN3EA5Mq5yPmbRu0UGccJWhcPkyHh900AvxwGOae4RKlY2AOh0C3Q91gk1G0Ldl1HYFOxbaGfJxWZi@GA4Dr0uNIxt5CBi0rDpGBniE3K@d48IlDicSgkwuPIom@POooPehxwpEYiKbvRHFygIyEJ6CAXtVaVAIcljL6EpQBqyazjuevjCLrRXqdFJCPWLKbxd5aIwDIMGorUuIjF6FTzT3rCyu@xEIxjzKtSCyUYNySco7xotUhNBCVYJt9XEtLQx/drkIqm/9YBt6ZdxVzkMBSQTfDWeg5rqT3c803neXjo4x0LiUUrSOPwnhsQqmBdAL/0M3ZdSgizLE4HSjkHB/TmT1ZyJWFku0IpcmpPDPyrlj05Ny0aCgW8egF3IAKRgmkeGybe@AEFSHcHUgGCw/paCaLJRi9hi/CWsyyzQiLV7G7vmEai0ZpTAMeFAA2C4J2yaXQGRhhPMkwnKxAJaGvpXXw8Vkx2LmYSDTATYlE2AqOZ26CNoUjgZEA2KgQpURoQb@AvxLmiJ87m3DOn12hZAN0OgpALQwmOYVTMCBfgBZUalZ94jtVYiJgOFWLxZJTG9PSvsiAL9YXCERAu0CKuzYC0NfZQQhUQxkNUJum3FFAXj57KWuaDAQCnhngMbvSEJjMjMTcE6BjkxMaKYUgz@KOsyURMjp9cmM9dKvizMZKskxDY@U7UGs@XqBe03U0m3Hyv08mkuXb8IpaGSdB14xUwyv9ihjNrEajK9pqeEVDbevJExxRu1sBZa6ZAAN1BEDxFTVSBn4G5a@yopVXpPXwSqeSXqUY8Aom8i1E@N5KJm5XpLvkyhNQlmLgY3KhE16x6FClVCIh3kH@sIWsJGPAM7d4OhCd64zJryjRKOYhsdLEDHyfvDiOUrd5cZykwbuyYwskewOnuc2oYl5NzJ1HzQnoeJe8DiuHHZazvLTpAk/ObcwsCrtH/eMJv8RF@IzWDsmW3/gSpkMeL1gcOY0y1xEyYX6qFRBwFAYi4mtMikRAmPz610Exz5jwNJ8J69GnuVQ5GsqJYKaDfR18Bnp4clUwhduLrfg1k7vp/Kf4udRNfGocXh0evo1chFmRhYKbB4KYFT7g0duPu9ZY@p6L/fgrGFxNBoLJVfHJWjL58eNHsDjgOq8mqiA@@BU5j4ca5@E1xqpra6uxfGE19izU9GUrEk6nI8dMUZLsQjGsTgd@ep8OYQ8H@fX0KaUF5j/8M@7npO843BcEcXyD3wh3LeWC7GJNklaj2fQzrZxIp9J/@9fLd7Hbw@b63/7OICkv4@MAHz@7e4XuYzH33fLydxsb2WwMCMndh@8P39VqtexWLHd4nnuajaeW1//T/7m8nE6vp5PLDcsSG6Hzq7dCOpUVEn/7F6HDw9dNywJCFPHKMBGceC/AT2S5HLtin@G66jL8J/fnjs8tobvV/YwnWYG9UiFhEwrlMqHjD6HF1bbMxOrTtf/yhwefgnawmk6emfC0g5@C@UKQO8EBbxn37TpYDa4jWP4uOE5WKhVwrv2Xfw/xqy8AD4aM1@FWzbm48uNgNV6hKF@C1Tw4xHQa0v2/f/KTQLA6Cn4OiqIYHNNfE91wFZ6ITxg6ksJaQdD1Z3hMPF4j3zUpRVIU0xduffqqG6vW8@4DbqhXpvv8vHr3uIo53ECOx8JV4VbH6@/@j7/747/7Q/r7Y/r9Rzx9PL/87OMWYzL0wHiVSs/m6mFv5v0oEYcr4bWOIL7GnZIFC5VYk@fKY@GgzzFDB@/OHJJ4798IFwi6R@iiHGpMVcZFUCxkD56NHn2xSaZd2gYnJPUSZ7N@bmV4L8yVBexb4ALB7yuVIxv/XrXw79DCP/Zglh84xIk9hWsZ/ugfLu8V78vk43gTyPy1/BtI30DwPHjeaOxo@PepT38m/rU@4d/eZ/z7ZOPfSRv/jj7h38ln/JsvTSC4vr4ejEaPQGV0mPYx1yn8Eomm8@YxbzAQ/K1eLADNoRGN392dJz6MouWy8w96VNl7w4u7IEeNu3h8/UM1Gj2nnJ1XnSyux7MH@QP2rFHluaZ7ovlhHbBH18/X1yv6Jv0SzSpe8caH6vn6NA5C06g@exbFJvsMUFQb5@eB4C3WSgVvq3hrW3hPC0KSXr@ghIcuuxgIorZb5EpvkXvQdzTwLRD8ePsxHH0afZpSU9cp8Uq8eqUfTP4PDkYQoIxSl7qZ6qf6YgdEJkvJp6lxajxKDfQDsQNOGf5SA3Aqqe4o1UtpKU0Ux6MpVPf/Dw50@9WBDth0iGmPUjYiTnXh2Ts4eAX4upD2JfwpqVRqBJkcpa7hP6WiAKcj@uj5oRm5hevj3ceLu4vAORM@yqAnJMRQIhVK5EMhpZHLG5@EWKh5cR5qlINJ6@IiyTUols6W6YzGu7tms76/1WwmkadWos@i8WdwVarRdefxNFgtP70oxbEq3UoNJtefXlQzcXTno1BLafSLfuM1wQjP6vJFAEzCszP8nd1c33AXOdB1cUZXkwefnSW5182Zc93Alby@B8GUg4Ey@o/03zn4r@v/1Slj4fNGBO63d@thuiL4F4nc3t3eOfdqJBx2XsLr8Ice8I5Rbu@q6CSgW3CdhyONyN0d94N7OLLOEVYxjfUqRZ4AQpMN8lQvQmXGwHoKOxNvFxejVCpSboGPNwQvfaE5nEiZVrestHDeDSwGcTVCILlsuZx13GuFcrnguMV8vlxe9aBS8OI4AUi2pHYZGb0cNCKYB87@4RQOvNBBuKFwR@7iFxGeGgZYf2Ix9eWL59VsdhSz2UT/zJcvF9CSQri4pVLMgU@q8OULtMNQBCzDfd2ZVi2CnScm0xP0fcmSbNsMg@0fuwjhojPrIhTB8HQqhcAYn@XW1/PZajWfBXe@EImUhRW@MibcixbFyN1KUuDFAJstFHSCxMJahHzvQhjOguvsaRVY3MKL3d4Fidosm4uEW2M54nmIxSL3Ydl8uBAtOn@V5QhLVleZ83d@nolmV9dWnzUakx4bpUT5VqqId5VbqYTjCHfltnMKLa4Klp48yRSBLIVU@SLQbG7VTmpN/JwHzlGDFGboSfImgPOPhhk6p0GfXLFxjgVpXIRCpfIzXq@FHAuGyg5cPASSixWKVN4gWJZKF7cDjAAr4g0ES@JqOrOczI2@y9dTYBGt4nV@fl5IF6KrINdWi8VGo0G@6xTjfDDqNugkskr8XMznGnHUYy5H3dWgwcS1THA1YNBKo7UU6@BkrYkDaMvgCVXKWjivbsmq6h76e6ObaudG6cjLgeDhXm2zfhJLrwPK9HZtM5Y@Pt0Iiviam7xTcAbfj@q1rYNTiHC4V68d15/vvqmfHoI/HhEK1@BQkodyU74ZDm/wvSnTtalY0uWlZBhNA65R94df/u4Pv/wffvjzn//w57/7w5//8a9@8ce/C7@/hN/P@fPn/66Yw/uvfvEv/u0Pf/bn4Pkf4fcf4PfXv/rFv/oJ/9H738Dv//L5/Y3z88HxXwBw/d6vfvGHf/GrX/z@n8DvXzu/P5n//cFfL/798U/v/2G8P/y3D8P8/N/D73/juFzYn/8Z98PnHPyfcbjf/5Mf/uh/5///yflD55//8Ed/gzfn5Xd//sNP//CHn/7ODz/92Q8//afANv/wV7/E/z/8q3/4D7/E///13/zDX/1P//B7/ws5/pQ7/p9//e/4/e9/53f//qf/8u9/5xf33H/3wfsvHuH/i38En8fn8zF4HlOub/X5xY/Kz29CjUkqwAPASP/8h3/1z4CX/oi//Y/wBv9e0M@8Fy8kSgZnPDrx/BljX5KgyqWeffFAAeX/jL7gzb5MYyPflOv7q1/8y79A7ynYf@bHkBLnYVcQ2EvtZ9gYvIz5YX@GzemHX/7kh7/4pz/88k9/@OXvoYSNZ4uxWiwufmXcCgBzj4BDwPxj4ABQXMcp/GW2HEiDY3kdx1kCYvTjRyDrMrjAKlgN5DLwFmw0yLC4OE9WL5IXVX414D2RrKJPInmRxPBEEoyKJvsODDL8PXu2yr6Lx/lz4hcQq4Qa8hiFjkYE622VD5tE0XiF3yiQLcIbDqREoX@M8qAoBG1EWaVSiQZGFQgjUHjFOCNWLaBZjIZgBfBiJB4n1iyAys1GG4QFYlaiR6y5WhnxiFH0qBIGhhlCryNBTAvRQmULEqyMthjiQuTRwEd4fqxUC5VRFdF9T1kAHNENSBKgKpi7UfV7eK8QToAPjLa@h6wUKtFotQA@FSoqpRZrUppijgpHZY8yKjf6g7kOj6fPGPtOEAsCt1ShZpgDjffoBPopDdg8hfCL6KpTHPp3nfRbxfhQ7SOiD/fj4U/Rm@I7AIA3HsfVY/CDagSAZxA84qiilCw8ohwDUC7qjD94HqSdRANRqt8ovUD6kIfHXetV3wuiw@KsrKyAa70qZIQDMHSYeVWybMnEyRVS4EpMyBcF9MbFOPLKIZlCq1urcBfhv75MC2o5OVYDKyFUVkLMTSMezehZPUi5d4tGZVmlnEcJLhCc@HPlm2bIQGvOskggTOf0R8ielg0Dnq@s3oY@AgU5JggxMc/HwCOOuf1OL5Uq34vZtQA86X2InwhwDquHasDPxiWwsSJBq7fxdWq44ASFKh@oVp1ZPiYGqsf1E4hwcsDEdCrBQKu@za6ls7lsLp3J53NraTGbL2bzuUIGhF4@lUunxWI2WywU1@4oS89AcMRKq63cevWfzF3/3T9ZdC32xStQfctGCRa/C1RH8XgyTTmuiLm18rgC@SCvQJVURW4/jG/juLgzcEGLyW5x3RJkK3AbRzZdgosFlgJsCbzgArQ4v8GcSffdg7Iz@4gfX@EzkIKYA0aIBC6AETi2gDF7BbDinoC0eSJyZy4/cabQeYK7AfchDagGje3hSk9bZyc6X1G4IbcD684@tmogQNM150DURgC/bnDeCKwnvdDFmDb7/JuEm6YOCviPh9mQtCsetKXwHUxe0I6ER4xZA8Xu3wNxagxwr49s/qNhqA9akEEcluUAG3AzVV1fBLDGTg/vKeUrb3cxznvS9mIAP9p9vnPie57Ua5s7gTzbONjfmnnkHKAc26tvn3ivazzUjZrzULyr7@3NvjoPNKKWWW4tFgP5CDd8xuiiZ2LlgwsiJh4Yk4XOKbnOVroM7eQctHmWBwl8UalKo642BBYHKzDZlFmzsnEuloONaiG7llvLp4pr7Nn@cDBESrDesLB7wFDgvRUya0JJeCqIRfEpOy0tl81b@06KBV7hQriiyDd0KFZgB6ywAX67AM@9sAOm3AGL7EajvSot/ALZ0GD3esIDvdBpKr0@CL8b3QUItCSJwe9bL4gv@y/7YQ@bp0F@cyHqAnCc@lO6LBVI0GBduljIFYqZdCFWKBayOTBWczExHRPXCmvFVExMiQUxX8gVxVghW8xkQUxCaK64FgiCOFG6yST0AqIg0FPR2ni@8Doe1Kwn@tVAkI91QNcblqCPj7CgFGx6vsMCEzKFixREFvALEJZN631XlYqAn7FN4UdiAbXE2iy4vb2Z2t4WhA18wVHKzZQgdPAlV0il1jYEQaaQTZDpaUHQeRwIAjCbv6RSG5uCMOQIcLO0IPTxpZ5HfVYQFHzZrG1vYzqX@JLG@AB2xUP4i@q@rAGYhi@ZDCnEgvDJQwdwNZ5QlnJaxxdME0O2ecgmhAnCczc/qRRgOOJwHMOOW9ZaTRB2@UuthiEvqOA5ntWX@FKjSxBMeAFuFIQeOHqmLGuC0AIn8qQgtMHVHkvgh6c6475azZYEYcwJhCQShBFBS@0rATQtxx@T2dnZkfp2R@7xa2zyZxuyBiHKaFjfbj1/3ur1Wua4Vn9@hCEvXuxIl@Oh2eq1nGitJlw6xIGQq8F49oI87jabkrow5CWEaDMhzXFTxrw1pU@QJ@fqYSKD5gsIeQEhi2aHODa4BgDawmtjAM8NqUUh7kUh9By1WkIZGdUeGzKODmHjoWVTsYHUNvUyvo8qy6FwKDY@TzfK5MsG4chtqnyHgd0wfY8GpWTkdnw@qqQaoHyLZRykCi8PUFLlhNKy9DQ8QncepJeYzgqR0vLqKHwRa0aeCmlQf0v4YR@9G2KhuPh0WBDyIOZW4QmiDiXeKJwKpRiDWyxyvtZ4KqwhUuHp07hwLuIrwEjxLKaA8nENVYPyHdDCho6qNbTlZjMcvpGlq0gEs4vaBOX77OwscsuXiY2prEq5Gx7FRhWeHTaOlLEwpmwPoZ9KzaHs4H7iYdvWTY64B4QZPU2VqPSQmYIA2UgmI@sonlCgwPPj2ZlvGN4bjve5@JVgpTj/Yo5YyEcSuPy8qXeb9O0K9tEHiMrjGW4SoQ2i7moi0putUuAENUz63ibDQwpa@Ikq2vULpgs/LYU@KCWDvlkMBKqOyoX7jRPbQw2LlsCPZtllJ@REHtmJHRnX/LRdv02@FTNRH@F3JRVdcwOOx6A1DBK7B4lTzZK6cvk2fha/o53HuKkT91crHSZVquCSOmFKiEmRG8pzs1qtNCsDeWDYY7BQSEmuenGhd2QbjEPi9hB3hTz0pFCUVFnD00SoY10ZBUeBagd3UG9UNm6HpRLA3pXlimyauikEhXL3qVYZUgYPZRM3c@weQJct466Jdv/jRR3hNoFqt3fxqsm0cq9yjul@wdt6XBAa8fj5lwaowpVUeRyUKtawRedVsFQLdPV8eQR@4lq2rEJR@Y6YFVoXJ5X7rFVpfRiVzYoxNOUygX9RoT9rJprQjs7TqWIsLUKPBT0ZBMFvDd6z8BPhl4bfWmN5mYXVcGqUSogxURZjtl7XgDipUglpBMSlV3hKkWh6VQ13dCatx4nW0HjKmDA04D4zlFg/DLGOZEnl4JHop6f5OMuKkXJ4OVKx5E9lP/3DkXK3Ev4QKX8CMpsr4U5iI/I0W@6EN1gzAh7QHcMvzfJZbgpQwYzlZiXFjYIVazg4Ty3nxdhtvBm/UyXLXhHX0qXz4cp5XIRypb701oX3VaEBBL4LgP3gHziHvrwMfm6z4r3/pP@e@BllUNVUGapDLKbLDkjAcNp4WGBh/AgcXx0WDoXW0qFQJFQGqGXwJlERuaUGHQJ5E3oigpSBnrUkFNMQPhENcznghk9eDATvAh3FMli2GAjeBu5u79arrob4ko3HUjTuvj5hrBcFEzhJM32JZpAtkyueqD5jtUqtd1QrO6C1TTJUkwF2wfccxpPL3zqfGF2vfuDPC5xLhmQCnDg0@Z5cj1aTFwFBwCbizAOFC7kIN5C/D9IxrGzztotiAhp96RXSSiod09cRzhuR7/cV9baQiVfJcgJuubsLRqFsuKykmiRKtQ9oNUcgqOmOE6cGbJAxID5zOQHtaJkZx8UPax8KH16dHpwebLNnqVKhVOBkuOCmbUwMiaF19gy0OOWoHggaX/Sc@L32ohwsGaFMNpSZ0ssvKs5u@zDyQPgc583g1zgHA7kRAVelIj4V10qK5UxrhUvW0JDNyFMxny6lU2IkaN3hVuD0WpCeYn4t2AhylNm1CLhpQiYtBqtJx1tcw1hx/gbMmwtaxS/BdKoQCBZeffzCmPvVaiVNrmTSyezK3fod/FfvztfX2R2ND9zRP96ScLvjAPSPEdwXekyuKbgJzCS88X18nf@v023zgOdcyEM9BD@CQLCsD80PzWAgWAyBXRNi6ZyTx5FjcaMuvqrRn2yt4t@HiceqZVmr3hu8rkKZWa4KBtFqMpm8iLxOg95eLObFdDDw6/kruboUYKtLNRbiB53xjg6POfW2m4WmviOHgzqrS/Gt44PNl/UT7OlkDb8DzDYP9hMYhJ@qnewXbKuyZKpj51u1Y4TCDvJk85DpJjvdOqQ4Z7RTlHxp7MZJZWW3U3I@6BS7ZmIig5OVuWQqmxRzTCyUUmuldJ5JIIYsPBnCca1gVEbF2tSNMbe2wpsRirxUQxgM21PAFrbkEnt@uEcx6NCI1aWt@qsDdrC/9y7h@nL/k53dY3Z8sH1yVjuqQzle1Y@ZUDtmu8cCO9s92Tk4PWG1/XcMgo9q@ye79WNEkAygCEMtkBPMM33YujW2kqgiWmT/THlbevtKtqf9JdOQknhu77S3hl/xkfHbF9P@Q00B48pvWh3XlrhixRC91OmYAdyiqrTZEhpTS6vQdeMO2X7KWmO54dvPKTO3zNrZ/dAaa6f2tcz6GlNTzh9Ts4PMEVteXr7QBE/@@4vhWXZ@L9zcAH6TPO2@ry@F81m2ClZcOhuZhOwfHC6l3Lels6OTJdELO9paSnsvu9tLGe@lDm9Z7237bGsp571t1F4u5SfR9jeX1ry3rfrmUsF7AyZdKk5w7m8tiamAS6xr0K6W6EuF4e3dvTpbBaBIeSoUR9TQMeMNhAiDRsTPC0GSs9XVm74eIwOhNZ6B7shfg3bBp6CWUCc7R7o2YmxVN@AG2h4AQ7SAp6NLZq8dc7DiGVfQsQRuA0tYoCUsEMAv4U51hGPLFZaOMAhe6vJ1E2F@5mGMCacW7Uf9zmLrqENXgRlidGgW7UuGGLLzydLA0p2DMtylUccuLbYmUBFyKphCJIKbGfdP9/Z4YgapkmGBIBnXKxfg1A3ABkWEOxYdfHnl8GqhukBaLTlKBX5WNXA3VZuB2dpEUkA5l5bagGCauteSGmOoVMVwUh7x4gvfJAHAEAzuFLj4Ls5wuI1l7cl2mzIUQWLWD7Z5CXFav8KmaznCMFGiFAXz7RdfvjD37cKefjWnX7UQx@0g59ni@HhOKwgbQb8ld/ssQdBRARRzCTkmGoXYUBwK85VrCYgOP36ygJvLKiSUCrEnTygf6/BWDFESGC9KKbI4giACh2BEPkTmZW2ZshtZSq7ightafkPnsmI/wo/RbY29U1FAss5mdKZWvVboVeeSBqZleUYgO0HdDtY1uDPpJryjeAROjrEWNJMYcwPFPAaiGRZjcox1wXtGpjYVDThXNicy0WUFaIxU@/tbvIb4EUDkzz2oxCD3SlRhICyeYPMlRl9aaplgaZddKJCHBAV8i0wTRkJwuIfjHW1RtFXeXpAtMfZjYu5ul1w@4rGBHRxOI7LiqQ2cV5zikmd1AjSH30GG7bcC6DlLcmTRqAPhcZkDVp@Gi8c53J3Ll18pRH22FMvfXAoUy/eWov7IYvxmpYBubcIiUAoQ8WHAGwVouk3XZnoRCugLCQWV5sehgA50wkvQxqcQPCI@dLmT@PFvjw@ddGm2KUO7hRrkUoFHmX5tT792pl@x@YKPxMAmSGfZF9ZCl5gHF@7eZwVwdLisnI7YnX6lUZoKk904XU8C8xSA51BUcjBkwHlhjBIkYeEnP6QBfniqwmrbzd39@sl0KOJLWE0n431b11RKIzIN5mQIw60wvkS8HIW7SASub4YPeRoxomfz@OSoXnsVg/xF2PqkBczqAHBzWsJUCe7cFMBXk9vQH3diLHxcY6sR9gRzFmPOWAG@PDoJVbdkQHVvip2hkaakUhzEe59uSUFskYEFSQlhFo6wLxcX0KWm1pg4ML5kBhltLdNh48waKrscj6eDOFLeFTD7vGlyZQMhO/x8x9LCxC5TKZY1M8yW@6Bxj1LmPH4q1x32bdQtunuMDZ2MMqvMcEs3yhbnRBboF6dVm4e1SOobkQ/QF5sx@GF3TiN7UdLPkT0p1FWweF468rfm5Wsa7XRe4jwv65TofB5@7YyGgrkUmNlHTgfb6IZtSLjV2gk8oDHUQ/QyAwE@zOI73yys48d@7EiJzqVBmdJs4sGuzWbYktUuMKs@NNvQ5aO6bDlgeGFoggdSQ0LHdKBDHtSfpgM6Cm6NxmMzodeZQYgnj4A3nqYYphQDAS9nli0blCtfNnCYDL@C7U8QDOypd6hW3LLoy3Gk5GjF2xK2BxfZ@dSRVBzH0OrHFniDeJ739dh0QZjHNgvC8OTBRVHcrfQLwi6Hg0U5AMFwT4izGXZBiKYfLIrAT3SaBDTOfQQ89xO40QhHFlc9tKvpGvcdyUX0PzGHsnO@1O6BjwVBuXQ40FfXwS0ZmLat4CcUZhF52/EhZngU8Z0M4LFVZMJJktVWlFn0LiYHEW1tpa8EsFGp3Qes34npQiTmQ@jD2OHHyN6Hk/mQQg4XIAmyY@J9dwDU8lAjC87incRP4MEWWgfMu0kE3XgAHkMnsFj5LvASnknmhXjMvKDJTdCV5hmH/HHMHatfnDq97T5otxBixE/Q3zT5@LcmH/elj23yRyVdYefT@WhEfe8l8JiU0W3gPyohN9fTqUW@qcR@rpHlq3vYF0/Z8SXDT9eYTtZD40ggj6fcohB69HikkEBcfkTfIF@o@py9/4tiT/qf1QqLi14cLvEmrYEG132ZD@C5IM0mHqjbbNJJis0mjiw1mwJPgTpe7PD8na7T2HhYArTUpk6hYSEuCTEhHq8db@7uxhVNiPFT6SuCZeum3MQD0YQYzgpXBBJYTYTpy6pREZyFfJLFKLZwfxo1XxpQwK8nQkA8lV2NEpmclPv15Nr@IumPKJI@k9jk9M5HpHZEqeFBBQ@lZPJj8NyENumkNjz6zpQVFDT8vH3nE/J4pMnUSRo4pO9kgadr0UifheeX8CzRo4l@Tl3jQSB7ClnVNNonuCf7CHMH8TitHYd6EMGEUzn3CYf0VS5Gp7x1ZEfPouGhhDA54dPJWMIpqY/fXQWNH4wy6dCmT/tx8htzxyYtHMacyepEsOgGFv5cwMOAoAIOdQPu3oFA4PaOBAI3HgqEXq6oAzeeCIQxuo7DORwIXHQ8EDyBvYXJaaQDaaQMhjhw4z9ywtHkJtnCLh9LQr0@BU5LP05RhEioeKxz2MEbiQolAYpu0VFEs8cRIfyiE4kijcC8kKXzszGbPtVhEdKFZxxFYr@FSvIpYiiaLSc3EDcmMIErIRRXLDXA@PTxjitiUH2e8dP5qCcigpLEvPiT/sp3olFlyrxAioDxwDMzicBHmfxfvyTlPlLyVJBJjfmhuOK2IN@4DvfejPsxuIpaJPCAJfX/GzvJXyX/lZpK/98bRXOmzz@yKfOACfPN1spv0Sz4bwr9f1Pof4RC/1vT5u9RyWdRzrf4GXX9q2r4t6tfJPPG0G2YvWscekv/GD3st6QIrH2THuDm@lx8SBf4ev/sokn7u/Uf2UsHfp086eTPtvVarXYyEM2j57VerV87wsOjNlJ70bPL7MbWzcbzjU5ta6v3ore5L78u1LJ7xsu3hXfPu58/yaC97xy8eP9ZNdr9wNsj4@ZMPrzJyAWrNhx@2t0Z2zsbp4PN49y7tZtUXc11N@RPW6q19erk7cuT57nj6M2nF4cvPg9SA@uwm5KKg8zOq/ybzfGZFshdK6ed7T3lYHDcqZ@mB3tbyrvt6GZq77j4Wkzt1W/eZzZvorlUctd4efD86PSyVX@vHu3uvetsftKl/KerG2M32Sl2Ny@P3gQOMq/FnU8HB716uvh8J3mz1TU6qfSOauYu3x4dbpy@2@m/lOqD7dxp8e3l@DDff/362t6P9rJn@eErKxvVaq9fp19qz6@v60eBlqSfmBn5TH8tGjc3h3pxsCa/3N/pDV6bopY8yL2JHg9ObrbqG@qntVHm9N3Z65vs8bvhq9cv3h@klOPjVl3KG61O@vjyJBtoDzK70evT@mlBet45ez243t3JvdtKvurL@7XOoXr1vLfzXj8@3NutZayhJu5tXqvvnvcvX11tbe6q@uGVqtWyyZx60nl3cBA4faG0tuSdt9aL2mX/XTK3cZV9F@0Yz08uP/evXmwcnx4U0qPDcUrftI5aO93R1lE@XUi21U9Hn7v6K/H0dTR/ffkirbyrfbYDmc/jXHFPfScPtBfRdu/96JOajJ6K4ub73c/v3h3vXJutmnb66c320aX5qqMdWAepoxcvX7XUq4J9abzXjo/Fduq5fPUqmpICo9MdC@pIPpFyayeDvdfGaEv/dLT73sp/jl6fXWXkraujN7VPR6nWjWa81cw9ZbCZ6hxItTe6XR@OnreL16dXO@repwPrXeBVXczltvWutdF9ky2@TT6Pdq@ev90Qj0epfe2om82b@29enylKvf/29PNRO7f9xigMbK33@vPpoB6t7436n@VCqqUev7vSAqe546PD9I32UhnY2ztHr/L2QWrvzWFnZyzWXsvijba2Oc5tjcx85mzrrfnuakczku@UT8PDlHwd7bwz7OxrpdVtv1Hag5eB4xf90/3DNze7ubz5fKApG4eF1P7ezuZ@r5N9Od59NazvtS47z3ffym@Nk/xVur5xlt96e5yxT65e2sX29SBzWIieqAO7dxoNvBj2h2uHZ@anN6P32dqgJWeO1Hf6eE0cbL4w0qM3tfrB597VoaHvi9vpcfJ0T79SU59Pbj7vWPnaOFoYndoD3T4RRznxdSBz89mwXxgvXh8fbLw4eP9CyirKmXR5/KaTypwWkkrfzOzm88/F@nZ38GlQlMXPW68yUmbQj1p7V8nOZuf0zdmVejl4ObhsBwpFq72x@34o6fVWWky92@jWc/Lext6JKJ/2Xh5nt/ZTh287h6efRiedzbfD0zcHSqp@@aK418u@PXpTfLn2/sQ6kc70ty/N/cCokNEtMV/M3WSOi4WDvnmcObss2u9fXuY31LOW@GI3PZC3FfNtYVy4Mj73b3o3x3Kq1Xu@9Uk66tZBkp4epqTc8Gp/dBzIvDkZXK8ZG9F3V@2XbzVRLZwpa8mTT5fFq37/5c1WO3tW@/xJyj2/lIvH28mWup17Hj3afH142ds6@1zIdlIbe2@kt6N6334XeL2jbF0Wz64ORmPx9fbxeFBLaWru@vgsd32ibxyf7RwX@q9aZre1c9kH2TAYn17eDK935LX@6Kbwsn/5RkrtvS1salb2MBV4Ie8OOkcnL9/Wot20XLSvD97tG2eFs1HuVUE/K@oHBeVlrft89PqgW0@tGcrZyei03k9ubCqDAsiUQ/XU3Dx4vfP@7IWRCqS1/MbnTT239il6PXqXP0seRveG79on6cGZae68Vcztt9eHb18e13aju63x88Mr6eBdPXe8v7lpvYhuK3l5vJO5sWqbGbWrB6zBxmh/ZBrFzPurvR70BHqn2Hl@kjnTrFqte7NbOK7Xas@t1u4LaTR63l2DPgKv@tkbvRL4NT8YMMDPBOQPiR86EhhYvZY@AnnJ9wUGaHNXgDZ3Bfh2LlohzVcf/zq5Gjjxb2WgbzfzAZ5hC5Q11tFReUiwXe/0Xvx4R4wNdIiuoKutG/REtM5@jQ4afCrcabwKdx7SlyflkaHqCn4XCb/RgDapOflIXCJwoLHBGO1NWx7wDRYKftrIOWyXPuvAvyBFh30Gltpt5n6fM0FHyXpf6/wICoSh9eJ0dnCPxePtrir1LHCoHXJ9DBx7Z9tjCqoi4eAHJiHuNSUxlXOWptI39TBzJ/hFpv3nTNX5RyNci0MCZWJMh67gIBUdvCLjN/ws5VpWx/QVELmTCPAVn49aBen3w9Xd03504OnM2lBQN2RzZgGowSO6M63J1Wd4Hs6z1aQzxYrKUFMyW4qNX4hu8q0STZ6iu@bNmF57SFuCnQlarhihZkNHBXPnQBrh20wspBitMp/s0MP1dJAiqKjuasPVVYNQ0rorxl98mFeN@3Erg95vC/UU7o4iT@HVgVZDoBVNSM/N2X9n0SJHD6gc4JP19be7J03nUzF8ieHUrqh7Vlz6qFx234wyL4Ev/07O55dl4goDyD4OO/KTtqGo1zrnZYHWPeLySKhttLAnqy0TwDW00gCxGbQa5Tzb4CsIU7R0zyW4F@cJ54Qnvlw9mRB0yVlQ4fHAI@PxBZocZL68iLhryjIB0GpOd2fIzGK/3zLv3VMzLVXSrtBV5ktlwV4w277Koo9g@MqBQ1leWZz1k3xDHJQbonrLYCcZFUyvWgjAWRDrVvOphs2Z1ttjHF7DXtI4PoZpeFaXqurt8CR41V1yw8sWcVPi8DNJHeBIYhdX1urmmCeEwzPhchlAcJ0OyQRZc1er@kpdmVAD0dGiHl8ugG/LrheePyBP8hljD@eWJ7VM7EArgBZnlS8GQqhzL1sNntT9shDoHfEXZirqhDjuEiJwJleZrRtAhK7DcdCNEY/w1alzVOErvTwuYpxO56kG/LOn/pcSX7iLDUrGYU8UIRFsxmihz2TOyzSCVr2mg0lNWI8qCldwYxUqxItMAQsf/ZkSjU7Vkw/5uYJ0E1mUqB1eEApiyCuRQ3qH9gRDa@KgNvhSXNblK7g4rQMzJFqHhL588RoMvHrceOjuwASW8L5HjwzOOZO3ZYegZffdbYSem0ImRPGk6t38WnraeQoGuH5jKCNZDYPAbOIncAwGXs6SJcPgDoLwli@BN1Y25d2RV8vLYYh1TnDJQoM9YWFxfT28Fg@T13eFSMRrjE70tC@6LzII6WqVhdOr4YwbOYuRAWVmGkF2MYI0R5BdDYsugrSDQMwBBq5iEJLvWIFz7TTigg@xh7cxDYMf0lmQ@mo6KjbW1wu4xtPnORM5vTjrq5loGiJz1EvR6RCOlgf4/BvTJQLkmbSvH/GhyEYzgIInHZ0OmKQ6E@Al6k8z21jYOf3WlBd3n4bb@VB0/J6nbJ4XsLzIqXxRusHAbdim44nfVDPoy2oTP87Sq8jmoCNQk4TU@jJumorxL@s5nRbQrzzTK/o2RxAEigEigotHibHLh/q61rd3dgjcpQE@XuYYE2OsAGYISBSQGAWIDCKEaKD0mu2B4cFBV1yI8BXfvAOjRPZxxhn3D0A9odrvpkRijJMPZ7gBn/NlM@pDOH3DEKG5t7uBjzf1I1wxu7v/HKpwCcsRY5O7W8xljtEr4qak8a@tKLYCWQDZxg0ap6y8qqbTR083fQebi9yBn8XOI1LpEILxyI52SHyh2E1Fd7BxUrp8JNtER/r4lwdQiJTBzmA3MpNUJMeYf7S4wL8RRpveKDaRChxeRCeDSCGk2clRbf94@@DoFVHusFnbO9ypIWYwMNuS2WH0FRtsIJomq7xT9egZwO63h586xzJJLfeTK/wj8AjLP4fIiQeATQppku9sjrC8nOnn4Ln3oggkUTxoUCqaHdlYgBvXrnpgTmGsBQh5LfJcO12hk6dFPSF1ePM9oStHqyjpiJa6bGkhGxibvuojaVyeJF18G2Bl0icRqeWiHtUjfjH5N@AyafowNPKRNTRwdljuCH7yS@22bNGRBxPqA0pZ7VIijmTxEQp8Fpd@Ij/43hSv73Vw0HcxqdNNeXrvRM2dVhZBe@S0@1E6rk9B4lhcHenWVStJLXJS5t@pnlIdlWmV8b7EeGqXPLVLSI0LXHY5q5ApjfPLKUVsEXkUlzyXXDd2NTOunnhLyanmutDorT6eSkRjIVzqUIVhNdERHPp4StY9cavsiduKJy1xsXL3sFLmEHZaI3M6nEn/6RjMnQ6QLTw3tkE7V8j6GppY//xFk2/whXpKvtHJNTEInjilCeq0C@eKT9xDdS9nICaQhrRb5txJrkGdiocv7CBkcTc/EZ@uQbswnVEBRQNpMdmc5pSVVEndcgxFnyeKVacXNjtuIyfISWdmdmY3dCEQ@vINh5NdCXwbH0@ogE76pmaFUCOHTHRWCuC6ajwOESJ8XIN0GhC3WAbKnmIvLkZhvhhO4VydTOE7YFDUOW6RiwIE/QJ2D/i6iZcXlttXDnczHEaO@AqWKjs7KNwdvaeHLCNmMr7tvwdn@yyfn@wOxqPOWDadmmw5xkPPWL4Y@FHjZJPxBM6P2HCcCkW2Qp5B0x10QVlVoRHzR0fBrh/zxs3iEX@My55ytcotWMsRx07XYLHB0MIhSvwqPc7X2kwciYnAEghFGgN2Pvfpdt4A2BtKpqTZMt9jiYLcmdnFBCki6rCyCeVqQcvAZWMo8fFj9dAtmDIfAAafjt6mRZKIg@JBTQ8HtBophgrDtWziMQCK7Wz0XyKZ47ADFw1VzgSupyscqi5vcBI6IoFaNA6ycDJSt4zU40MvjitN6srJXopyebInUpfmfjkYM0DkdViFaMzdgSWHwHPdDNnjq87n09wm6QFPRP@iocH5ToYbp64d7qDhfcy85a80FgzGEHe1/X3QyFnERKioTI2IuweOJIC7BartjkNwIHqMGtQ9ES5ujSIFwX7pKHwsnJGMIC2CeinqUkzkOlyl4xx2R8FL3rfTiZ8r0PoizsqAsbNhztse6UAgy0c4hLM3chYC2yeHGPlxQC54Q11NTtYfjBCHt98NxTdxiGuFozvi2AWIgNu1pHbx/PM9aYtL4bRRSpRvSZvNKQVFfG15MRgvsgOGpfOBQaZIHrmFcsFODyf73lxAyj0NSD2U@anUHpt5J7k5oClKPDLrHiHunLG6RUgh8kC/lvkklbOsxlEzffXDlSSoRIcRiGep3TtDFQ4NXKnAc9fyxeA6sxvHlSQU4mz6nRc5DpTnWE2724Fdge4Nc0729S4qKOdkt6huMakG6fvlqmJQ1zhdVqdZ@MsaF@cLu@YrrLvLeKqwTiS3nPPnO2jg6Kr6DT9/ATsUwdm5LHzXibHvOjgZ4vj4@yiXGovk3/ReZ1@D/FCZtEivfF5eadOs98LbqjN3iKLdz@8YD/Gm3EaOH7CmLkBEcF0ru4vreaylJUedAaVnKl464gw7e@zsouh2QV7TUn083HYv7WKacAxhqbDvOR7qgj7L5hSwC/aF5DxmIOLBdhUoqQ/Wx0WOZJ5qpC53YEA06vRnlanR4MkG6nsZ0Y/FkZ2@LcoPxieZMp@LMYbxbnIxDjeK091P2n/Zn5HxvRlBctAckdPXeXNG/EiEu990ZnSiuxmO5gZ6l5GG2ydHEXP0t1zK1QPCxkRf8KwDbg/4dQNH0XaVQRzYAgUebGO@NTrGIPV74ScnjHziE3y4NQ9i0gkg/mh01IRfIPEcpn1mkeEzYuazSbVDFDV4nUznmyqSBkI87LwYT4xzRJZMx3EakDuj4lypptAx2uRMo3FlfvgHqbJ4MDnZqf7TP7DiV7HwOGU5sbMM3BzsrnYgFMrAUGW@c0fca9YOdr2jrVjfto1SMilbOnpZCd3sJW@UKyXJAQPHzrFVcXmI7RwPqeIhzfopdGV44JSdYMcyX6yAei@qZR/JnJSHkY8YCU/A0gC42wWNV2vL@NUW@wbXDzgIrIQ/sxAsWaCH6xob63prknvJ2ZnDMxCjvFuQ@R4QZthKQAaSbcm25LGcxIjJlgq3gYRHTCfBJE9iCZMHmrwHsY@hSciJS@laCmz5MkY7p2dSpVPoAnEcO6IQGz94TqtHcAzBxnWRrKVD3XjrUx0jgU6R1DV1zDQ8AqAHmK4RGqQKJIWcdwPFpBW3zqQOLXmQyY7Ipop5EvaW08NRPOy/EwkIy0UC/GO9JdzfYenILqZMa1Mp@tSalpk1GbxhTi@i4Hb@tF8bD@f6@joNb4lHMumLq2uPWfexaI0Hnf8FZL9v5UcyicOjhiqNmXAj0eHebDO7lsqX0NZSehqxIbYWPETHp7HLIwM/eYsLA7Afd@Oq8rWssgxW4xvFGgLgsT2EIgWChin1BpILGM6UGCbjO6OL7OupHf2TIF1Xp326uG@CTSxq3JnGmDjBRju4nF4Fiel4O/2CHAGpBbenuORZ1w1WAkdHbg171Bngviw3Bu6OkmItjCBFquFW5Ck8S/CErNOx0dCOsfFXvPOrcD2RrrBzaOYN5k5QCOUAlQKafoXnvuzGx54DwXwzOtBh81kN6BFWWdMxRvkoAUBjHxbmcBYf96TJcxeko@8e4KgNJcgXF7shWETDOevx3jUlq8y3pgREAp43hYxJR2Alk@7ISKiGHy92XzZCPJRGjcLcPRki4r3eqkcOd/1Cl68@WaczwRid4UnkjJTdVfVimd25gLgGBDUcXFkSD7krB1DDNHFuZrIiBUgvuFbYQ2h9Gch8BZIqDtkM@yVfMfgC7wYf7XJUkNlgseHOYYF/JVV2qcG/de7V/2Qy6wmvzSUq@DJ9Of2WOeq00OYTMTRL4kwwTeUVOy@HR4g7OC6niw9zfiCPaW5wRhNp0DTmDajyjPIxVxAWqHPGqUuJsRHr4eg7N59ibOy84oH1AX4qdSo2rohl7@hqWRsObtEYifEoQyOGwHdMBmlfDuDdsehMnrjXuqGXILGOgjxAggK9zl1/HNq4TcWYeFemlNv0DTMu4kGPmOf9hWuxLjTEVzoHU4T@G7ybKH3XEWI8PZwyIIfoOtKN2CQ1TkQv16OxfhUexcYgOhjuR6o6Vge6ncF5eh37guiMEmeexhEwOA7blHDesYm0C7snkLHmqAIGUnNcwTE8fv4XKry8WdABMghfYgAYjyMgWKjMVXYpnMgMom8UjWI4GHXT4UOjhFa2G38uHGuP8PP4fvx3k0PyiA7NUaw5jrjrUiBGc7xKJPCWp9zNFZey9xuUdy6/M@Wdo4dX3nvo4ZV3np4/qrzeiPFbKgh0MfRAGwdN9qdgUQO058nHKZ4y9ExNeqitd7OxhwZ@iWgmNn1IYj62bhi6hWeYL84BT3NBJijc5w9pPuVplMANBnKSDx@JhRQ0PfwkgBXgTdzUUV8Mkxu/Rcn7L9AnVT627fTR5IGYizSi773GZ94hgYjTlfi9XJHolQ@T4jKVqxOgtl3R@uIK8yVV9jJOBeU2GKPIXukjjL/6cPiKTssXITduFCRUhC2KMkS9A@PNRkG/xVEcqjvycToWUp0tjOVWIsZ2Vle6mhCJHWGXW0kTrVvwzTU1SToDu/r0Cc@O9cZ7R1GXwXll0EhvKOr20mCK7XZptG2TL8Rmh87oFG57AhXe7pv6sNdneFAU6oAIy5eUd3XU7lG7BK0eP0A6xLNqSu6yuPCk@N74cZKdGgyMfNo/jy331SHbRMW/NcaxZD4WEPZ1E84Kq6UlV3damgxpL5Gk94AbfKCPjzhMkqc682VgC/kBsvAKR@Ig@SNipwUJu51YXPQ0EEGybTxUHzVrhRcBiz@JZuA0zCQiagDuGV@krCx5oIszy9nYl1vKnT@7e8Aqi3KbWphJ2oY6m8mWjEN9qQcyx0cRZ8duIDuYOuZmS/5HqD8vVT57DXb/V1gTEnW5MkZwMhi5uDgalB3cmjfAA8jxZA3OqWCBA8p93UTbcBxbiPkGx@OodUk3YHuRqYxw0YSTnT7Ys9e40GhhbJpx60tQVbR1ABFBDki14nNnOF@GX33D2K/IHPUicwPYIlUOz53l2dDbOMvsRp6nhKm3ZbljocoqIa9QPsO4vcFpru4sYUeRemghgqXuil43OzQeTdZiX2nzXRmbh5gVU/40VExubGNuElCXtO4HWGGzL7evCBa/cTTBHv9/2/u25TiS68Bn9lckG5zpavQdBDkgmoUBSYAa7JIEFwQ1UoAYqC/VQJGNrlZXNdE9IBTrvW/shiNsy7Kt9SV21/Ju2K@7Dl8idh/8PvoHf4H/QD63zMqqrgJAajQKO4YKDboyT568ncw8efJc/FENhm0U1YKBCn847UxQ5BBMVKUUFmSP55NmTzRx0nyUbFDtBDBRnrvIhFjAyH6iK8gUWWl5HYpq9J5HyjoYiqMUSiAMkRnh2NqyH5Sa1BXsV0YgA8fzUCx0/ZDwWNfvqhpMh7gXB@M65uFOmOys/YWMZfemy04ME920PhJAvLEmcy2MooYyMRgcOsblJOad5mrwewvQWFUOcI2hzR3LGl8zaDCUiXFLPO@QUVAsv4Bskp87SG@hhhmgrsXEkysElmmWq1TJIlo6ihexjoJRzcbMYIuIAQ7BytedP/cbmj@FDNAI9x7YYND8HSWMvQ4KK6npcvuElU69REKWrsA@cDodRp2RF0zD4fxXTQiFGxTMU3hnSJrT5/flM8mO4zWMb2cNDAagdhq7pO6Gugl4UYfNe@XJOuYU92WrwYk7DeScVUMxgwmrOjoPPhM5@5j3RPLwcNQ6AakcdJmAkh5UE4jIxqvKagOwdZK52CiqUzmtYNfpRVPaRE8CVK5AndIpyoNQx2OCJmI0JbhhY18QeTD2JlwZUNs8mCp9PgO9xq4@YYOMfW36UKkcfYQf92bsFtI9HySAB3FbqFDl8NizysD2Cw0HcJIdQbv18db1REaBhxu/bmGoTqyBqoW/iNtnG7i4wg@ujV/hUOaLVSLuVLkmuhWAxWZJyVjP3rkp9/uyvuin9J@IZdayLg3LBCW6/fiSQFoVi2I5fYH126Ro4fguamrcRwsLWJcAeuAf3nTxrYW1Nkh2hrN4BgTidSa9E@gSzJePBBNNaJz6fp@GDe5wKPY2rsxDBegxhFGZGejR9LSLLmkGNF7GTJPePVBIDiBOjLpMNcemlz7tcH4F6PkVqnqS/LhfNmuLq6J7CV5@ANDIkfAElTaR/FIGBr9jzSYzOgNHPlEUsoLDgt8HkohuSsQf/ULWyqH2XG@ufCvtNMbWJRjLsfAsZRKGAq/IUnE6CyZv@OUIxW6080cdn@Te@BbICstYSEv08JE/jPP4JUML5@KwJrSe8WA56URXC3k1NUWwKQ7ZoIcNp@IB5je8dqy0bLSRm0xbsIX1WALVkCzUjOKy/HLJG7shHv3myjJEtg1q2qZbMtauvRR4rkWUyXZtk@FAuKsEbQikUARC65aj@F1EkrqOGqEhKG4833Go8RVXg7XF3Klmp1zg9Z/bqYdPaMUbbTT1amT6cF2mjrgOoyTcs1R1l7V5A@uTJYafwuq6JoDDh40b7RgsTm2rmeh3kaXVjDW8bqTu34p7fIAs6Y0b8/cZHRoLoyYey@SLRM2yDOjeYZQBV5g2Urc8vTEOeOlnmKqIkieHO4DjXWEwBTHfgE9bGB5GZfNcLws0jOphRLRjnfQ13n2AvrPWXWcYBuLKjA5WLhTSe@H7vcToFcjVy7rrTgfYFHzphzKxgcqidcrNgdlySDWXH/x5pAic9A6niIPXf9nSFtQO9dlqBaDIZEVe@KXggZaJI3pRox6IjIx7oJaPpFrpg3ZhhJ2gB2/LnQ3dqr4z8Y7hz56PLeqHJeSXzMt3vbDFwsTnuzvP9rf3jva2v7u992KbSpIivzEono4bJCkLz9C590jwlsKEQ5zC5xMfznE8cSjOEt7AX/SCKFKP4brrwXX8TQdKdqZeIffNfeVJft7L0Jusc/l9ZubJ@J40jUMfTYSmqKoE/TvjCzg/DzthmYkfzkBySIVar0P0ZMBxoQq4Z8Jmzjm4f@JK6gYUPJogxLIBj5RgEJ0hByi3ieQbM5w0wz6sZq8uOrYaGkUOsb8E4xABGQDIR63beZ1CmNtrFQbeA54T2UhsK4cghrv3o6Z6ztVuUbVqi/uFPGRnGIyOC@I9wWoBcW5waFUxQPq6HmIyCoIqUG8BPQXiSHOPuEMNvB80WvVm4@tzaRA/Yv@avBV8gEn@B9p5L9rpZ8ZPyjLb1zEALB7nImVDlwiblGlBlx2tKWlQl6poRSr6MHPyfGtyQX/712xBnmNALq1b/WaMxr9ee@5rm1n/0j4WvnkznEwCTljlaPLNVDG9@PoMdv6pWI28n7nIVVYU35pOZJtOSEC19zGeKC2XSPsYOY@dXRbYo6jJiH9Crd0t4YxSPJnetRKKtiaCTVJpPo5HI5rI11OiT2jQJ9TKf2Xq8Pl9zbAFiLubrXb8Hr22jCMSHW2@lya8CdRzhYq7ra1/kWi/rtdW20eV9skcec9YkIZrTpqbVJGm3ebdO5VQA2dLF9bxJfIXDXNj3qKdylvCOK2MLmeHlplxyZT6OwsFM0qbIG@RxMji8FrJEHNCrbZNosA12wmFeLlHlTWui8XxS6mtxyMYC0vJiZgtxJe2Oss4NhiIis4GtD0op@cogTIWxuahTE6Nnou8ymShLdiEmBf4fy7WVoYE2cDjWyOrX6OR1bdWI99ajXxrNXKZ1cjSzcY0nDS6/qgBrNlQ1c6A@y8swYLa2lWff/ZgX@1/tq0ev3z0L9X3d1@qzx88g5Rd9fzlwyc7jxT8f/vZi21FBcy/73oTVLlXMPVbXs8j6fxKs7mqCPNCgPJV9aJzqj4Let5bIJ77Yed084Q/6iMv2uBS22@9yTzg56AxKrNEYjVBsiJ@a9ISJ7S47gIln@I7ovbliW0kb54hS5bI9oLCoRsDbn7bIx6E9LjoWckYbQB8AKmApsNPsqQ7jU/rxLT060oGzvx77xEEpvDpC/Xg2RZG@tza2d/ZffZCPd7dg8/n30c3O2prB93GPHyJWQT4dHdr5/HOoweUwA1o1hXK1shg/bIm1BGcRqX3ZjDF8GBDvBXKV8Kr91KhMAq0VUSoStNR7L6nDySF7@7s7LRNLtqdWw/2vvNd5Gq8H6piEYNcWg7VxQLhVhONRqA2iaLdZmfqyFrWWrwhnc7VLcxuF0gGRL@rSiMv0zux76niIxQj4oM0xc1mhk2jhopuAm5EpR3BuooiMJRK1fuEcgNqI@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@qVJkgL4bSLpbU@I@@WuMo1MmBcTnxgvjeP2iaPxaqL6SOKl5VMp8R371wuVSN7EyIhjCQT725VdaCrrFKZQ1UWBPHeCY1Fz7o6pUo4zX69iXHtcRbaMCIj3EdIvcYOq0b6NZa3a3zQg52lIHwaT7fBX9axyIWi6J9jz0fjC@ehW9koNzQULSYznI7eoqsac6ssvbrA6aXzagHd1uXoYP@@Prq1S1vHx8N7Ydu6FNt7ta1WycfFx5KF6/pof3QJWj7cPggt9L2aj5gPyUVshtINcVZvLWmav6LGHyzMHa09QINnL0ZUNUit2qajIXqIc1goDk2jAmUbTcwQvdjf2t7bU8VtlLKtQ1nY9zqjHtmX4jaIuG9qT0dsh0ybXd0wTSZMkGGedMoFm5cmq71sMWcOXs5WITxIVcbDbBYmai/cTGZiHcEnC7EQaHjNG6IeuWTrzvUeFB4I4osD1IRS8aRZHSxkdnOJDx92sk@bTDxuVeaNwzf@2DAz3kycdZGoejK3EWlGGI@DzjG@fGfP3@fMH6/repjB8n44pQ6jEn4P/eWrF1DxGF@K68kZvGRa9JSSzgpR6ZIeOzLLS3LYvzxBmVjsF8ILW9u6MMfSNOaPb1mR7Ig/3cR3/rlk9k5F3qm3eEq5b09oOT70nOQRBEwmXIPVpk0VUPzwQo4wGg1zTrqGIbfX2i1qzYFuJUUzE9ztfKCPgIO/cze9PaSrgt320qpqX09VfEokarLibi3WoDMB8907d25fhTvdC1289svi5jMkvX9Gp@O3HQtlOA9JVQgod@dZVefHBHDJ0LlwC@w7esGkCgKrk3GmJPpOh5HdPmjL2QRt8aAxuy/3qygvStdaVrNU27Kx84lkYyeQhT5YS9h0lFfNwuhfXF7dQwrqdkV9N9@/Pl5sCITy8ItfcJjMvWCMWyUw4pMj9ooKV/L1ELXiIizBwQeNp18rBuamjmN5wPHmNvmFG22kucbNKHiDev06cqbENiviM1T9tDM@f4cCrnckMuU8tAmQsn5Vbb5mHRWOrLnZD0iJYGBCWW5yK5NpsM2/PbKDb66j@iDlMYD1gOmaASx9XFJw71lHqYIONVmqcBrwJyapxklAqxHePUz6MqejXYI/Hs5NeoPT@x4GnjOp9wXLWcdEvCxtCGQ6QmapKMAkq/UH8yMadpP9KWcDG2OSPpLGwN1yGJjUm5yKOlU66UDKTuOkQ06Cm5RJWhIoPJj8yKal0PPeHNEkS7Q5QFiqqpE/PKyL/tSnjtwdy2LCEfFEQnlv1C/QpFDMU4NKHwmb6FpWSOhg0z@skwKlbEB4J4snlhfSph8XsIEh3Qp9yUTFxagB@F9phDTVJl6s@WDzNVL4xAt7U09tz/COr2MjaqokxyBLavvZltp9rPZ2n28nUWOLj5BHoVJaYY9CMUvDqDt6yVZhwoNpdHLEifoznXvmca5Gwd8GaBRMLCD@TOfqCgjFIS5Ldf6u/04dwOE9NpPi9MuHMum6x6YP9V4wHUXn72bvaHpnwOnVgQQ@VRd1FBJ8ujAsshKFw9bkQG9xGBYS@coj7VYhroVSqJaZ@OYIxOI6tebLF4KtYPZPmDpYmbRJxwE5YZvEnSBAlmdd4lvCcPRO4oCb9JbtKsdJNwwPpXp9IbmiPjGBGz074m6ysmtWUsmr5F5cCVOYwVMPMY5oXFtZ9QP1zn@nK4sPFTz619K3HTPa6LtZptE6YmjZJWCah1Y2v0pYfe4Xkr8WFpzMoErGG5XXDV4QGOQ93s1dpvEEGNH3ApjZHDQYL6AFOFoFCUBeJguAVH4R41F2K@Oll1Eku8XxelxsTk4tMbqMItm1xI1OTkW81lOz0QuAO@OAJPjjCC6C1vmaOXNANgsV5y1WlS4opEjXmSOu0@E/5Yw69DbNEECPh/pn65BNb1TJLnYpfHJE7BZI560BwT2I3KngsWant9Lp9pGkNqziaQirUSlgwJk6qa6eC/Ykkkg6Q0stXlZktCXRwJHXkqMRtpxDC5RIKAe0lgTlVRPDAiiCEBeHJ4sFyisxCVrJBrWIn@BtrKm2WqvRgFayQa31sYC1loU1CVpJgy7sa7RRJsfeMLTLzuWTV87hY210VlXezOtNIz5ptNMKWEMRLA@b0RLovn/sR5@qmNGiX3VoDxLt6pp4xNZpcMG/84lhfaiAZrXtJki1MULcLSxeys@omMVRNvsWM@aGeUzAc4hrfB@3QA8Iwp4GxR6YpCGayZALjT7FNCtmDw2XmkWqTcZIqqiWzuHzArnfg6Vzvu5w5PditVi@KHKz2oldFPqkk@V@dP@@Hot6FBz5KvNfWxpPOIKxSuKox0mX/EvgmEYmFUUc1WHQY2FnFXG19WXtANLxAk4POykc@Jqy2BddENAcXt0OfFBZxIFNqKjLOmXj0JeqRRzL18ahL2yLOGrXbwfdp7L68tG1cfBFMAtH49o4kAIXx7S4dA4ILvi/xSxSS4wHmkVJaqfaTZKGwdlJfHXTfdFXVYX2goQhAT9LfWW1Qxhzm9aH1jXoWuOBl47F8XB8XkkbcBTTzt1kAXMLS5YX1gtfbimVJbDWymurW2HUh4OgPhia9Z2x@FNX9JSQRBCS3AMvMfXeyQSuSDibdbl9aAaEcEL7j45QNevoiCRDz/d2v7P34OnRswdP8RK1xHsUim9QW4bUdZr1FYxnz9KWI9IpchWqWmA3CrQPW3nUPkGzTacIRY7FUkvnFtxFkRkorMkleVF95J2px5BFQesXcCJk3chmYHocaoPZ1Iu1t8VyDGmfYLpXcl/bgJYQDNOJtIRgrOSCddni8q9GrKHyavQqYsCuOmCbzPDQbu8rNFyyCipVe/sq@q436aIuSc04LeVZRBV8vLuRcypUuRAJeozBmsBfNBrqoXaKK/ZrnWEPXd5OB@T49tQfdk67/U59fDIuDEJX3NM4pUGITi4LqEy1s7@99@LoOcbp2n5ElhP4r015@ztPt3df7mPOC8i6Lcnbe3u7e0ekoL738vk@egxNJRVtQMESg0lCAujZ7mcPnlgw/F2URrJBSAj3Tfgjrnyqyh8fzei/czLzqLIqxBEF4SEzFSxKaVUV@adeMNXB29D/hD7gq2h5go8yUJeOakwOaRwUf0pe7Ov0woKidkym44hASQPeSY1EOVmCYU7DYyxAvohC4NtJm77OEmXMQ0O@YOykyqKBDBYriH3XIKTVgcvkxXzUczQ6ceRZPfdGAImvTaVpNKitlS7K6FVyTEpD6cKlBpwcDXKOWsouKSMoWukFK4iRLXZtF7TBO0CRRQlNQmyZQgX4BbGtKhW/fF6wA0RJFuyqHD/qXFk29EkYiV9zw5ojdmvKer5QPxKI@SUWOIZG@PO5/ShFBCbvU2TMcYCW52bM6K/uLEuYHTM7Dr1PxXbdddQeeQQNfhA57OiFfPbFdCfPXdKAI8xIz3gyD9DL25h0mCpkGg@jNgxUNJkrtiAMIzNc0PND/O9MXLv2UIHGAYIr27DFIueyO0o0EgojBqBrXnGjuB67sWGzBKM4zBD3bYhWFsQXNsRKFsRbG@J2FsRXP2YQf@BUKnryNtTKnTuszZyYz4zi/8cUr9U07H2tCh0XBnx2cX0aM5JtxiHQFRfNQe0zG5DbLbt7acuSqL/6v4DbxiWlalQJN/ySZl@C@ef/prjOErprjNLvcw@tDQqZE3nyYhNmlBc@EhLXTRJb0jS2v7oEW7GoZzG77B/EFPFFDtF89dcJmGyy@Ymed2XGT79w3YjLtmKrhjSCv1xE4L4PgiMur9cXeRtlA17MXlk3WHQPYgQMctsGWUmDZFX57tIqmza@VmaVLRukeZ0qv/pbqVPOrwyIPzYQtNfKYGaC/r/EQiPVfCiUBRoyJNrUPI9ffXPBj5NtsItlgT@PsVORw8vb/fPfSLc7LpkJ/28ziZMK2PSlpz1z4P/ndXHczsXxA0ZRq@WOW4khKpVciK9@FreDhze9zC5bJD//91eXbuaX/tdx6fiY39AHN3MNGll6CzTqQclMKnpgsPH8wQCYlIzWWMeoWXPWksOzWAzGkh1omWyxOEtmr@jseWb2bZOdQn7BDJbmktC/HjFG9znCILFG8W@y8mWGS2duuDbXVuYO2dwuM@tiYA5jY3gcMcWxmJ6N1IVjOXHJWEQtuWVh9i4KxAW3My8/YWfSORl1MEBrGIzqEgHEDxrbp8FrHw@qSQPdXNRfh3m3oV@GtSYEdI9z8fr6ABUqoKniVIR1v/nejoCdXm96Oh3iG5or9yp0jNRooMs4ugiOpqeh4MQT9@HUH0IPXOTUYhYRrnljaCWdwsBKX6v6VNVZ1S5W2Wiw3nid3NBRErWtN/HHEVXmLt4F0OUTMahQhX/fgtUsPBqonxMidkXrSn@e@CPPseAxiqtftRLIL0LF5VJtooz0mFg4qqgB8mx6msBwLjNOujEu59RDtPhxmtUVHDkP6UZNPIwQYqwj/FCtiA86ci2DSMSCaJLEslJdLfMoEaLnQJ6nSYjV6koTKxpjFrkoIs/QRrO8MyC3RWTUSjgIm4GmWQCOMEYv47rRhN5BhmmXW/yHP/nxfy@WzxsNnUYxdfxRB@4MFJEkxoqf@8Fz/W2hx/uJ2CqmcP@PGDej7ns9/7SDEWoiCzUQVw5mmEDEfA6Ehk6rgiHsN8GxY/mC0RUiYTUaD7a21P5ne7ufozUUCxGIClLFkQjWVbHCw04lE/miGIwgQgmLME@lYgTSjViEMr1CMNNjcq8zcCwNLBit3/qPNFokyw9Q053XZQohZhfZqQ/KCVG31kZrJkJTMM7Db/0HxhyMWXs2G3EwLgphws@xB8SvRZHOQr8YIru@v//D/0LViUUJ8HwoVzm1q85j@in3QASyRLO11mFurxLV0CDkIr5yiH7nzwhZyEG69UZYuGHvigZJdrf/@HcV4cDHB5g9q6RK4KlciegnjMi8HtDI5eKrXYnv9xhf36dXABtRd57s4lM4J@sTNBpyrOTGFcP3938oLQZ4P8I3k0vqWE40t5A5GX9hzyyVlenIm18Lf@4M/5GNVMxc8zDyQZWJ58d/Gy9Tu5vsOpnp@4a1OlNNy@zwj/8mi/pIxxxWD3oAZ7T2VGWulZw2/@ZvG/yzwo3ZFQTzD3/y05/FfZzl9myW25@fxqtpttiLWV7bb6S2pO/hkVGszHKn4q@T1SRW7sy1PvMQ/FXeuM@Sgz3LW/JA@mbRz65Y9nlIfqKRmAU/u3LJ5@H6PY0rc7Gnu5Wz3Ge5y1xjz1noKfzLOc2Exfjn9mKcXTbzuWs@nyz@GyFHhg@NRxempdEQDqdJrO191aK/6JkX/26kW2PvfihqixkXFzgqQIe3pgTtIdTsvr3yz9Mx5S@Yr4lTW@JsQffIqqUltcDVpDMMM6py3a@trhUcOrjuZdSy8WGVFC4ajZHHRvfTcR9vHfR@d0o3jwk9/2HwgOyd8TdoLoHbhusKW9uQe4IDavIhveCEC@SD6MjnkL5qoAfoPlw36O99091ai1PovnEjjWUYMEt0g8TpeBXKvYjITaLSOsy8VPA9NXMh/C@zA/Htqsu3Kxws6SP5kY1zrty8f@dnZkcyoxQksadQVq7G@acyDaRiRG/l5LFDeLp81G7iy1ykkqn6CMg9uv@3vVukqsvnJS2wPMx/8J/MQeeFqMvah/6gySt5/MfgmDgwuSegtX/yT0LglJfjLSO35v@sJz7kHSqvcjzJrlFPTjV/9u@KSNrZg8TZ7asvWYIx946ldp6ply@299Tuy/3nL/dRIGM7RjR38PyLHl@7eV@mC2xSSLBwl23DNX@Fr7NWHpOXX/UrK2Xq/n/9KXaf0VbcYrNoDdOl5f4oUa6ly10yRjQV1x4hGZ@F8iy0gNZx3dJb112TEYIL9M4owvUaevBDwFgwwQ6f5Wxj8meTafvWLRUznmtM/dfZLUsYky9MwKMOJ8BtKZw/t/ktZXwzlEEiqzm@3rlZr3mMH3qhXX4S6DdNQQnJZrbA9@zsrD7A8FTTiV/3QnRPFKJjuMb4GJiFUUBCTXSbDYTn9@Bui84Lp7038a9arzN62wlRQebTGapEu/c@nvPfQp6MeHx8yqE4PlROrBRJe6vzaq8KyKrd3pvq4Kzflgw2DDYKJ5yI3M9Ef5yG@pc/HhiIIEI5u8nqDt/0giFxu8XuEA6yYlw191BDzvWnfI99NozRQuS5eD9VxDQ7rEih8NGAcuAncFXautifHcwPE8VnpnhCmyXkiJiXImWFYMxnPQ4KGzDj/Flcqa72YCbO4o0JGb4@oFKIhkQ0cw2TsAjHnBkrxW/gCxWmIeQ8kYaWPz2XSuvx5i@YR1cTBtDEGAbccxoHX7w6eHU4Cr2z5cNK47iKjo4QuitmjTSm5LOHf@PoD98Ox0GYSBp5YcQKLk2d1DsRamBaYcUXGauUxg00yyjc@PGgoXagS5m4RT@IHF/MVEkb54Set4sHxXiMuWEH0hgcaV8rGUgaPjxZpvY2okMLEaabLulIfFm6UMXPJ@hPS8PWYMzRAcxojmaEGKghuVQkhqm6SLYKX8s4AYadfeCmuqLzYSoOUllWNy9k/u3m33zv5g9gXWS3ngiWN8WU0tjMgw3Xk@XCHjE3XGteoQWN5c4QXf4Vt0fknkYrDpbbyw1tmsL1YBck6Kw1@T1xPMEvqSPRQsG65nj3VXOXlyWvCz2kRtMkfoWnfE0IUp43EI4gklHMk2IzuxjcdHnjoGexrGJnViNn1MgZF2HoWU4jD6UYBvK03TYcotO2DpxHgK/FGr10LVRh5y3Gp2JXRMsNU2e85xAVaAtDmFCks95hZu0HVqOtTSuFAAlxAUHfG3Smw2i9kN7wWjXzZfYoHkq9R/GXkAHvFUBgtAW3WanMMUQmLxYoSvfJ7SX8OigUW9VmtUX/a/L/i1WdqP/fWkxsJiFbycRmNfW/X0niIY5s9rWo1VzFDbnwiyU1nkcnwWilsKTMma3ozEZ/hPyC@jrk9@Fw5I/HXkRhjtSxN8LHbQz86gcosUDnXxhXB36/8ci/yLpGrvgp9uh1eISIjgRRfTxXxVubRRj303EwidSXQ7@rf2OM8rur@iuch@hGKvQ84oFCYILkmRv1ffcn851od4RyiQZ6TI4C/t0dBt3GKVzlvQm5cgxhzQOEH9Qn01GD3E15oz4@i5MZQucNNO0EqoOu9Y8A7Ai75ZSR8kIP3VMWX80GgyI5b/GG/RceMm4oPVImkspOn/iOTnhSxG1tST0DJmyd3a1oHybGSxeNuKdK8hhXG3I8Z9IYKFmRvlDjHWNZkmZGEZWi5b2eXP8V6/QADaWKZWLLnDKdiEEUw2tVTinAiiGJEthHDNLHjDGeFXGPMESoh5Yl0oiKUpJA7Yg/pdI4gSqS89mvAnuIvdJWtJ4D08o8Y2sd3XuirMxtlc1O4aOdVGttHWNzUE9wQHGa5Gm4tYY55KAyVBhxjn3T2P2ouNISAOQJoUCIwGNP0CND9zUpkaKwDg4PpL@6zkPxRBddog0pxgvKr0beMUVJUWddn0PB9P2QALBk4/hLfyxDVE2Qand6DKw2rQWKrOKH4dS788naKjWI4hpp0H7QS4CuNAAzupZtUONOotOh6cW96EQNvbfekP2/cbMp9gsvSqIzR7ZPFDffLRPpwFAmegqj4NyrctrW9uMnD/a3t6qq1rqD4GygamAda3A5u0L5ZMAhZIRFePnWu3dXmcidsFrabJTK0vRNe9grdoM1AtizJniPGzsll4qJZI4Rw5Wpj3tV1cRbNLHdUFcblxs2ZTrBqAVFPbh65S8tFZGksa4lJMHE5ghlyvGhAV@w8SwA5e4VMAKyux3hJQxDCRHlFu/frNXMmlqnXzXYWGu1DbYzLz6Ce/gbVdqbjhK7bYnWTkeVYJNDb3m8td0s0b5QL7bViVv6KCy1kTs3nNNbZ1o@1yH@RgNshcMDtx88nOv5c6ZaawUGpHzQOiyXJaH0d/8frn0XsVnA0InK58hff@lql7B13tS32YOmU2JpMBT7sh55s@gRba6RG7VNgW7Qn9cpJGn/EZy9fedLu46xUz4n7eae694un0OVkzHaoYxhM/T2AWO5jWmDRFp85Xj1aoRucZfx/vW9p08@gynfQ/9SYXTwxeHyrUa1VIIjnjSQXIz0obZ2nz5HScKkXCeJwuNJcCrjMumYSur4sI@Ww9T6ahG71sBVCDvnsRdJ78OH8/3O8bPOKdyYOzAESQFOx9b6wTD3qMtvj5FbTE5usXx@7BLUycQbtJkTugjdt85xuR3BnxO7ijtQhbuyQtgjKOSiA4HUqPsjOK0/23/6xC3d7yjE6masilKla4gDCIUIxsEkutAmSAfD6SJVRWy3SQQD/yql4kayL/cbnY1S@@Iitz1Pgk6fPX6VYgLuO9OqUNzEXZzS9iSmgvnYczGBj7bvbO8Xq1AW776YSDGO5rRpsTNiV9fB5IY7BR2B8xcI47qrH39MaVhkGrruSrNZRvWQC8BGPiAALS@sSfti0nH7jhnIztivk@jcm3FdxJys1FcanVF4Buxoo3W3ee9289Nggu8GfS/sfRzCFuJ2MKSsH80/RkN@Uic7DoaDjwf@EB@sbq4ur@36D//V9@69uLvl9Lr/AnjI4uswwAf8ydhuwKRzJtp/sMdOekxd1IgR4Ox1GuPOm6Cx2m/21pprrU/63id3vLXm7bXeHe/2ve69e/d6g9W1bv/eJ51P7vS6DXQbTUXqp6Q8WGTyx2oH16s2jzFbW2neGwxarbuf9O/cG9xbad6@vdpdu9Nvrq4O1lqd27fv9lfWuve6l3NtcXsKsMHqfRfPjvQO/FE@c1dY2NuldPkfAQ';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU  ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $f &&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le./_e _=B[1;#]>847576097 @Numun Cr gu8IO nd eX"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t}a,
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);(!)=seq;instance Num();f=(^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

TCC is [Tiny C Compiler](https://bellard.org/tcc/).
TCC is separated from GCC using undefined behavior of stringizing operator:

```c
#define s(x,y) #x #y
int main(){ puts( *s(\,z) ? "gcc" : "tcc" ); return 0; }
```

There is a simpler way to separate gcc and tcc using `*"\u0100"`, but it fails in Cyclone.
`s(\,z)` is expanded to `"z"` in gcc and to `"\0z\0"` in tcc. This case of UB does work in `gcc -E`, unlike `\""` (see [answer 195](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163569)).
`return 0;` is to get zero exit code in tcc.
`char i=!"...";` is replaced with `const char*i="...";` to fix tcc. Not just `char*` because of Cyclone.

Code in polyglot:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i=...;//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
```

Now `y` is used instead of `i` to separate CPY, that's why `y[2]` instead of `y[1]`.
Now `x` is used instead of `z` to flag for eC that `main` was not called.

Pushed Prolog further from start of the line for Prelude.

Answer (score 6):

## 219. [Spoon](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Spoon), 10390 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNdiD4LM7@g30JJfUVSfGapEjxIlJFSVRJVbqVLqWqklisJJkkU0pmZmUmJbJU@tDuWXinx37w9HgNj73jbnt2sF5ggDEW@@DBeLHA@HVgzG/4/LQwFuh/0HvOicxk8iKV6us2dhaYlJgZGXHiRMSJEydO3E42Jav3618H8WJHujrqqrrNbNmyWdtUbmQzwTZG7LmkWNl0JhBAqKrZHfRlzbaKgSATGVO0ltKGd2br17KmfJZN8E8zZph615T6zO5JNpOtlmTIFtMHtjGwmd6ZHy3DWK2vXylxjNlXtC6A2bJpmLJN4SuMnWmq1G@2pamQ7FSChgnhFtuS1S/9LzZr6f2@pLUtgMwxtq@blozwLdmydIy@ytiwJremkOYBVDIVfa968GIqqMDYC8iiZKjykElNyzallq3oGtIkxU4Ozk6OpmKIIntzur097Ztmr@K6xrYHrevpoAw7My1Jlabxr7DqwNZ37Wn/LKt2ZU1i6UQhkZ4OzLENU5qJsspMWWp3FFVOQIWwOOvJqiGbDH1YRzfZLmRJzafyqUZ1HDPRwrj5ceA02gJTMxl7qjzpFBBeN3uyBjlMTQeKXuBUQNoLaCuUgGSOWNjq6SbwkckGltxmt7rZBubS1FEkBvHZ8DNrSpacW0EEGQ/BtabfasBEtg5V2xzZMtN0LU6REXCFiXuNacZKZ9G3erg77Z9j6b1pv1VgtNZ1Z7Yu03l2rBujad8C21f25rFzJsUbwqbehtqYChPZkQRelMwk4TPpyVbQgtqFxsyuLMhYW2aWphiGbPNA4BXZpGCIzVRFu@YN/MjU24MWNj67J0Pa2GCRH6xAC2JVmOGIiQQ6WJA4iINBDk70vuzPr8U0GSrIMuSW0lFanLHkoS1rFmTZSjAFCnGrqCpryypEGGNvxZilY/WOvZqq1Eu0EgFkTEyF9a9VprCWYTAeBKWALG2n8kxG6rHPEK72LDY0@sxS@hBst/ROR5bZZ9noQfRAWw8wuFrGVLG8tyUZYDTZJY1sgEBA0uhIaaCTS6FbUwLSmpZDA1vpA2EVO2QxWbIUFKgQxZK1NlHV8EStzqQJlmc3CjR4KPrAJNyWbFKTI7zQPE0ZUEpeNYdvTcW2qdWwKjuSJZOdmrIcmRS7E0lCYjqmYGNBElSpa2uh2uF2CCqXx0hIBlSmmTl9/TIgsUSZLTVK8CsLQilQO9hid0uX6OZSFhjAMMNShJW/Z1by8lKG31BsJrvmfQCwBoAqKkvqhp2U4gZkMG5DBpMSOtEVv0knDNWXMFubqgsfy3GoNtQGCB/2JkYlaw1ME3uSMVGlayi0qmtdoCcU1hxoSA@N5VJQBS0dOoIYk2@AaiB5qY5ALiCFT3sKVJqFVeJrWLw/JIJCjwhs7FDUTdfS1QHBQUzLRl4GqkBUxLjbYW9YR1JUjALhiIrn2pStgWpjnIHWxpqH/k5uJ5ibDWqwJvDxDSQnAVLyANbv@9olZQqAoSJ0KioG/fAHf9rudgFPtdUC2eaw6xvW1lvUc0uUWegOGTIsCFSVsgVwMUydR4cEbiRVaZOAkLSRkwRlglK91Qdqm@mQoHmrQCvtSTfQsqFxtWyZMznv7GOsL11zaaJwzoWC96UmVCwlQGlTsePs@SbUUksOBIln4v2B3cmzuFFjISv5IbxeDK8vXsqQuUgisryUTHZLwHCJZfKCt9BjnPOmOiEpLVuydKUdMEZ2T9fSLN5iQqusG7IWDk3gCMVCZjMUSaCUC0dKSrmV6ChaOxxaA16sQMKhSKlVbl0oxXppKro/SUBzi2iwucrhVkQIgMihRnGT7IM0T0Dn8CbuuHxhutVAkmNwwueNhJn2u@EeQVJ2kC91ZBCQQwlLlWUjnEqIERQTCDe33Bgwr6RTOJwCF5V6NBQMRf1FJwxQ0omCYmM9VXQUW6rRw04LiKJZBvQEJvJuC3pqlIyWYoPGGWNN4mvqRUCykEy8lUOmjF26x0fUJHmTw/hxFJQOhnETmmzJctvXkEEIQFu2rRlprOq3kCDlCbsZEB0aJip1oWogMi9IlReEp0Q@k0XiigZga8osH28q0AiwuYFMd3jeVzYAz6Q5DGDjjcQne/rSCLC0eLc6bjBM6UBb6oN4AG2oJaPMAeEj8w4FExlQ@7NAx0ZtOxVPZ7OTbWymidlmshp/D0L6c/LRloSF9zcmFDSsI98yVdK6A6krc02MSa2WbNiOoIKSWDaIoun@hjzjTueZsHqBpefTaVMn4qoW4zRQyPPac7pCCaWLo@jHQZ2RmeQMVUBzNEEsqaPp1AHgZipx4SOCTGTgo/BAFlwNAJhMHsqtgQ1SDRj4tqe0esCzmDuNy0XeCU0nD17@1EGyxzte0pgZsfIsHUgkPS/MxoMo4lijs3igc0VUlQkPqny/x@OYJas/B7HuZRE6Ap9vIiklgPe@grOva/ocpEBIDy2CTIbwegBN7AQVSui4XLWLGqunZXpVBHWGA4E28l/Ptg2rCP2EYvcGzQRwSvLUHO3ahxoyS9I2R4qtc3dT1Zsgli1on0k3hWRr0FSGUwUiP68Or6zADShgHYuVoef@NACuC4c6FghM8t9EYF@QQIKbUPC7AIAElABChTsWieJtEConI60VFhLUlBLQ6IQYE7DhCjDcETCWR5dNvY9SiJ2TYoCaHgz7FA3HCo7MJ5Evze3qPNlPel0olLjSFS18F1pcXAwVQxWQ7IuL6@BaQ9c6uqLgWidXnFwIl0AXxYiRC0MvKAb61UP3Fy7mYaSO1TbEXumzYoSli2IxU49JF6LzTOMzAqIOJBtAx/EBeEKRchmdkYhQuYWCJpqdydJvonQ@aZmK4RDhpXQj8XeHChkig9I3cBhpyiXsZB@nSb9sQi8ISmurFzZDlxepy/rl3WU7enkfimHsSEkqN6FQkF64n@ia@gC6y8jFSjEu1iORiwx0ks1yKBVaDofzcRUSkiKR7/KRqMSpHQ7JILXDl5chIKpDn4tWzyR8w1g6EvFIBfnAjhl0wnAocZeH9JuReiQagriRUAyGGOVQCCjTQiJYVGjkzAkCHR6/4oTZjEYDxIa6eY2/GbEPfgkYYPHo28C/myeTw97@NUhX1rJUVEXiJtdG4DW5zD3b9PA0riLbJY1Vg@4WSgC9bdsbGeFoXBuQ/kzKre5PiIaDCEF@2PegXFUmYBBxRxnCAAHa/chVhLD/Rl1oEwacuionzkk1ERg0HBz2yom52tAR71YSLWvMA6D3gNNQpRY07El0lwK7BITA58nk/JBIaQbxtKpEo5qvlRE6lpakIf3aCmntA8XqIXlBs8KhhNkBqqLKDrqBTFTbZS3o87tAaXmo2FyHBz46wSg7khWOoNZY5VoXKnuoMWCm3DkA6s71Fox3ZNAcMJQPHllNu1FMXUMiJ2qAGhi@hHUwhXweeYGNqtXd9NbD9J2HHCg24y36aOvHOk3cltViSU1X9a7OlgEAWTOR4Iy9q@FUCeh8NgwvmaV8JgJVu7o2muJBGbt7C3VEMZfxtG8JIZMEn7gCWcPmF3oM8ECZT3bf16CHELOpFOTffUvR5RXSh2W6jOjZYmMAZ8pWRb7BmnwvG73RxIQS8gcfRQI/6TJvmHxcL0GHCrlyWvhniupv5NwH2rkb1HZd88peIw0JpzL8o4yJ0oMyCO3UKQ5vNlDC4JQ3@rqkmEA6U@Hj@kXBdZmckFvewCne6eu2lHyT6FkMbwHUF@IKE6xkaDGUjMfxLlAQS1dYsi3fJFFKOZhBKp/2BnJAbvV0JlyC7uIHEkCE9kAJj0MhZJPUPC@aMzkdsPUB6IttWVX6ir1LE2mqhkrRuMN3Q3E@cIzgSJHtgDOSGQtunOwaS3Gty@FrQ@zqrIBMT3ZwuFVrHFVPd8pCcmCZSVVpQttoy40@qLSqbAls@gqyYxmQOfE/X6vHum6XOSNcq@yrVxDjuNH3thp7uxvH1eN3PBOExlL6A1XCrBSXpgAw@gkFu@3VN8PYMfW@p@tbTkUsZZD08sRqAg58ndAVDB04awk@/xz693F9INEKdFstFtf5q@fpAK4iIK4ZUO/YjUYRktYQPE8HMk8ocR0hYTZdzwJ6eisIE3PrY3Tzwh@O5GC@E1P3iNzSBpbhK9mdKJL/jd3poD7geafJ@zqOjUgde2fIm69ATM79O2SZCZoL7OFbIXx85WIuvpmgucAevizHhyse89FNhcwD9ZDlCBmukMzFNRUwB9DDtEqY/Ksq47A8hT20pOKkNTf4wUge7gLhxmWXMSpahHG8XMA0544@XxKxGjj7OuaRtDgRikF8IYXF2zDsWUMQ5JcvuMQCXqAfWkY7YQ/tMYqMH0UctBm@wOKFc0YQ1YbUgFY5zq3r4wticRUEmJgbR856kfWpqLoy9vbAeb2m1QaIgIGvSbs@/iAvEq9CdyXH3yjSvAZN3Rj52vJdmhO/rzjixNe6MpzcJIdQ7zInAjm1DXc1ZyKMN0u@gtO44tOADWcBB@uFC8JT6NT3dFDF9hSL1lX9kjHgDRkuA4I77plQ8IVxSHo8/8jiN/MnTgU/IpLZIFavdRxuj12NVELMIhYPRf9anY3ZAa2VbhOgM5maDeF9Rb/ZodscgKIzJwfdIi4yIVVe4roCThvqMIaQbwmMZhcIGVBL0aTkMT1wnmFefiZnTCYy05Q7A1CvkzD8Q/dXwOKFPEF2mk3lIVCgC2bdfc4t5PEAhjjpxEpCdMdTOEMJYyo@3XG6e0iA0H57M9NsbKIq7IFpQyzn@Z9/0oYqma2wnjSiQYbnaAAliVs6D9afExVf6Da/rgnmaqAqEhGGXF9D2ZJwZUNSPcd81KjTsHi8J5l91OWd6gZ2xRu0t0c4j@fclNVBW3af8xMpMiLy5HQe05Q@a82BJtipmUeeGI3eVF1qExn4GEuRKZKJlc2rQR7y0YZPmQVh9FBCcyYI2XhFzu4N7AG/4yLc16pRMfD3EBEmYFNZqSnKSd2Smor8SLWb0vWgrceN6y4VGrOWmwM7Ln8T57PiHVW65s4GOucTgBfRVLpd2XSfD4Hd9mDYQOOd5C09HuEMV7VipCxLj@E0VX5/CMTdBuM5HqaTotLtCRXtMRSxSAsaCZIWV9rjPjIpU4RVpeYIx329b@csTJB0VpAz5VY0mspgJ@stq4zX9A3j4fjYM1P8QmF@bL7Gz0kyb8yS5Gv7cT7nRWV2Vvu/0sih61L6khpPt33OB6W4O586ds0BpUmAeEuVLGAm26kO@Qaqj26PMTj2Ri1kq7HrEfYeZ8ddXXtoocZppU5LbumqYmFzVh@SmtNz2@M0cZcF3cZR8W2WsG1Sg61e3HPNlwR6y8ZVkgcY7QmSjS9Q4BKQj3MS@kNEa@m3@HtQuejpNzK/z@/cPs/N1RNkVFwlllBacwVou/U1TsWVdrrNp@P13HzZLXWuv7MeMDkUeCovW4qqWzAmx/tjpADt2rL4fT4X@6mmSFqcpq397vnRnEwZLOFM0z1Ql5La1dVcvpuU4PZghQ/MDkp@5/lUiedJLFH8usRy9SBdE53ng6L@Omlef40TaG7bxDUwn/ORfnae2HLWTh4uIIwfcGF7fuG2U3mKmUjyCZKHKsBs9W6lkfv8Eb3JQ9R1exNjRHo1qHkYoZAHh21yXfvHpLbyeGrtp4mkGbSrXyuEr3KvVRk6L7rPVClLp8RvjCGmUk8XUB11IA/kufLpsHkl49bGR0YbT89UyinGkjOVmATi4USiB/XZGTU@KdfYb@PbowJGUhVo5F/VbubKOwN0cQMH2kfgOELHbMSuNjAmKnditKYdP065nuG2bL09kUkM@VaJlP@6DjWhrlsy/R5S7Wt9HcbGeh/UBu0J9e8gpVkPfp9ATD5jRWNicmRu8t5COeiyoHpAjSrXVhznxZ8mdNIPDegJuFBIaoom2yO8P0TpeUK0qevqt9QMyNK2QluY1ThuWv1aDc2oOc6eCTaeurBwGqTZeWjSgvczzuASqIfjZvuRkbJ/KuqR0eDMtPojvZVvkv1r40voqWlWyDJbrvshhqTJDzGRT6w@yo5cC9WbsirxxzC38hi@QiLzKD5P63DUW1qUwYUcvnQzXlULTokeYwTEUtowNunJfZleH1HqpfbVwHIfDwINdfzNCU4kaSHigXiGAm1dw/vEMpFPG7J1DUZTtmR2ZRyOqLgy6vg@JF/d9Y25xN3tS12Zn3B4THSMZyVwMx0fxI2d8@cninx/Swui8eX/x1kBGs61PLLc51yE@6MW1Oeg//VZtak23sLZz6826kRy7rLOV9Q9raf3tJ7cM6lxeG8PNQ/gSJufTXmsEJD/nmRd4@5Bkkfj0VzP8lNX1VX1KdRFecilo67Pn5it4c7/NkT9JrwjqQkBzuOrM3bQZRORqO9@qO305AH0TJZu64Ycp7eHQFWc7OH3@XPNu4chi50rstnmWx9AHYeklaYqs1sFsnBl@ded508kNVVdwg2qjyjvQBn3@ZSpqZZufnXeoyvptmHQo2GoA4tuNKMbp3Ma84q7TTl9CjMoNt91wllW7urNVk/5WpaasmRrynXSncPhr4@OSx1hTCVXWHwLvROqArQyRwlkgrI//AQfuw/1f74lnLml3xyY5ujrgmFyxd@bauUrBOh4KH1ncXZOMHX5uK3K3T70yDKFs5b7IDeRAo3KclxOgVYiPjgDNLGDzJFetKj4gNIzVW7KjG8d7VumLp3NADSJp/g2NID/vMmLhwThjiPfYFQY3hl0rcjXGbfXBp0Kb3MRVrt4WIuvJFmqfuubaIamL2nOY26v7K06PrYEkn10DSSRdNY64/LgwdktVTEsfmfxTnoultnF@1mo0fyRrlM9bbnDlynQ9TXNrq@buI0eVIh4y5StFs54o/TlUpGLHE3vghSOq2wM7MLOLcLsfoF5uslkDxd/eyB3JdxWt6fgDjvVmu30APP01oGnIH49kCzl9UC35bk4p7cQPAXlvtRVWjsTteAidKnr7MHij4lGgF6zFXHbUyzazew65jcczma0Gj8bOD2p7p2qe3wixKcXOZtKWXyXuZtPPQdO62O4NDetSa3TWYh/UNApNk2YOs@55Zy/3eKxWYTbQd8YWM5jfup9PJvgnznuX5O/dauAFIx/AqHLepJqz59d9k2egj7l9IRj50Na9ntF1bvsfT7FQP0CAYdK9wOMtQH98pFkQwvQ5jArpf/EdUucm4hzpcb6BIwgZ1hc0RT78XkY25ZgHOQ@sUBc1cKzN8k9vCeefyuG@Ol8quw9KvGhSx@1VBjZfA3q6N1XIOTNr3ctX1l2ga5S1wZ2HM8rPtZF5B7tIopsmM/5eICFX9f2zyIuK3R7Lb6X8SuamCXDiG5gqaOx68HF/jkcpuA57YeF7GwMd2iwJXekgWof44reU@JVDUPFmQ2Q6Vv6vCHM0Qi6mG8aB0EvMehvyS1cCXxSHg70fVDPoN8yQKr2j2Vcup8SJA9Hxqh7ektSgWbtJyV3QujnlfVUMuQNqHP1G8vLMW5JtjQPq4yzf52vjd@LuBrUlM0rfmb9UcjZHOzIQxpaPMwyXLeJ260WV6NxRm2ipfgG2ZAXQ398qpLvnzqmo8HeITIr5ux9Bj/FdE6wWgn3mHiQ9onTkTL3iBEL4kG3ASqrtm4mGMGFw1I0GokEeCRc8OtqAOZC0UFdPMTHzwBbDGSCTbBKh11csKW7YTFVFO9ZmQlFgdXrHCtedKSsNjTolO0xj36xJNXLS6F4PLQUutSKLBXywGUVur254NIEbEehB8/vmARMk/hpAHS7JS7xQ4pWjw4AwxCvDUPFM41mcHHYyY/a8XOcp7ij6G//su2ci@7KUNi@AqonEATNAuh9uaffrvN0ndShQUt4rhpxgJai8lN@8c0qg@4TxpT8OLR@y862T/POIUvHBgG8HPExh5cLXrk4q4lHJGxeeTw33nZ3J2EvllsoENaDvgaj@LbdsxLA3nT6YWCONxuDC8E028SpjHaM7bK2jBs56FALzd6pun5Np9MwJ3/7l/xoKR1tcY4cuMnTkXJfiniCRaTznK2WPoBcu0g@y6bugISRyKCzDHBenGE3Rv4RPPBBZ16BI@PuiU9Khh/73KyesHiNhdC8Ah4kKymd8FL1@MWbi1S9/D3rJ@X//JNk5M4hnPBdvJCzhBhzQUr3yFj@4CwEj0NDTFgaCjxB79yP4gjhW14fQCKJMxke/XF5TNcNp9XQqX06pO5xo2M9Joxuqmf36GefDvwTw8q3dPSTdsVrKILxJL1mQQOD1wih5q2uvBQe8Onb@InNspAgHp@VwMVNBNBJGDzGiFGWhuwL6yGTxVt4OgPeOCFVPDnbL2@4W/sy/g2YyS25OaBNRzfpRDpTpuIsNcprFXKZclvHE@wXHy6H6VT8crhaqyctl6iXl8PvUum3QHXdhFjPktjyagdbd0uJSurLF0saMUG4D5X4hlEQE0t3R7tHtZPT6unZCdTCvSt@tnWzL41lDXIRnbfo6SrZBgC6mIpsfYP88d4APBxmSxJbQ6s3kUjAv@GfQB1aC3FhiTt9omki9leiz4tvyb7wWQBHpnUU5nLULnQDWIfAbEg1LPzAQAsHzInrnNImLlNQxmMD8giD23LnyFIilcDKQKw4EOuJpGIPF3ad@z2FYl/F8jjZ1ueCIMW89C68cF7EuSS4/62U24CO8jcvN8fyeLkJ5pFyA6jn68bZru7unR3XJqMBj9GTpG65kHVOunDhjC2Nz/y6x9LpuKETEae@ywITKAJ/dTozMmnUlO1bGYrlCMdWn0cmDqX8C4ExYwJlymgXql7itAiHKQeog5SwWFMHcTrK0JdFt4/2obvjRfSEwLbgoXYznhAczEGy0ZPAyy0GYnXI5Ta9IxLijrwOWX71J@a2OCwa9tEwqqZYD3RVXq9jMfj39UquK11nQ@Z0Z2KdxVkafqqsdaHALmykxPsotsQJISzxvAteftE@DOSpfSXRDBTtCXXOGkEvrUoGGqNwoA90Wy6yTwOdjky6wsTTL25xfkPippCoalsSloaOYmo2GpZw@y3Ct7t9UkbtjKtmJN/9PDfQsKMCIJ9hIhg8mWhDqkOynps44STXHWsabldJSxKWc3re0xIsdqNYtGSBldBBHUcFSYmlcQqOVsHosCyrqhboJG3ovrkNLVJOEnRwgZ9eiGtMCAJPJjyVMcaEAMJa5VnrCtCV3oIm3/rIIy8RHGG2fDhDa4vxOFCuq2iuFasirqzQlHOR2eYA9/9UQjNR3CwUyRXv2X3VBzjHzsylnPzhD/6U25a5tMH9M8c9TG3A2@85bx1w/74bIorw9i@8tzS8/Zy/fUhilc0a1HCSdwbcD57yAL58LsyUCWWCa8qLyuLVNtb0m90jZtHyD9ZlXxr6qgklDPKcogG9lD4wxQ3VMYLzFMZVOMYTvngDLAJ8BfyB6g1qNJSebNbDaFahmExixnGOKkFHA@QhX/shKwufBmhdCJSwZC6bWxGTkMn4jYuQjjp3cXM6RxiJFEEmBm4Uo/yx2cIzR0ywYHAsl3MlzhvJJelDRvjoZXQJYAN8oHDBIA4eU/JiQFjFiRZekqJiBKNiRxYSQyjT2jpnNdAGw@QAkAh6a@6JTlA3dYdUwMeaPLRJYxq5A6AmWpHDOWuZ25hyEcUBEceNNnCmm@N4uzkez/E10IS/GoRzBDtBsKIwj1kvPrBL@1KrO7aQGDDeL@ewrgbufz7HQBLnLDz8PWuZJzxtVwdLw56faDoeS9iG3LJwOpnOJMVcxMehgoMK8otN/QughMYNwqIlK1e6YVU3a7svD49OZizMEGRoGizEQpW16GU8Ebuoe46Ql@9Jom5sJ0/2N7ZdUvpzNd65gxDj7TvT2ZyX2nROH0j9nO/zn02bAmYSElNPRUxr5fFt2t02i30cmvQBbvJtxjOphiN39xf1tcqlFpxJ/ss8q1vBxDIyF7guLbK5FZrOJmZx1z29cIrWPK2Ee4wtLYxtynmH7/j72PthGzGebdCxoRj3nESADlqPD2MnHjhBAWVPJHlSZCWFZ8zNL8gaN6siZnWcYCsws/vKnxvmlGXWjKlzktAj0iGfQ3KNUFoc0iLhzGeZyFqTRzMP7tTFiE1/bLrFsVnSg9ypSjNw6xyvd89hekfrE5ahKnY4EtAciOkTmbOQ1qMWUDwwqXwxZN7RQgt1xmGC5u7DZGDsth7gBmSYa@clSqZijgZAtyPdYONZtC3ZdR2DTsW2BnwuV2YvB32A69DjWMbeQgYtKw6RgZ4hNysXaBzFoUSi386Gh5FETx62lS70OOFIDETTd6I4NjIjoZUU0Kua80qA01JGT4IyYNVk1tBGyzCyVqDXcQH5fCK7ne@t1QOADKM2I0U@cxE601x7YFjxRRaKeZRpRmKhBOMjKcfUF@0goYmoBNvs4X5bmvrodBRS2fymG3hn3lHMfgJLBd0MZ6EXuNvezzXfZO/HRxnpQkooWlsehtG0QrGOdAL/0O35TSgizLA4GR1yTMy0p60PubJQsh2hNLbcMyXvCgVPzk2KhkIBzTPgIVUYlECKJ7a5B05QEcKdvmSw8IDMN1ksweg1fBnWYpZtRli8gt31LdNYNEpzGvCgABizIGiHXArZyQijtcNwsgyVhL6W1sbHZ8VgF2IiUQc3JRJhSzifuQnaFM4ERgIwRoUoRUIL@gX8FTFH3DZtwrFRu0TJBsiCCkDNDSY5hcs0IF@AFlRqVnnmszwxFjCcqoVC0amNSWlfYMAXa3MEIqCdI8XdMQLQ1zllCFRDGQ1Qm6bcVkBePn8la5oMBAKe6aMpXmkATGZGYq6V6NjYiiOlEORZ3HGOLUJGJ6071kJ3Kq5@LCVLNDVWuge15uMl6jUdR7MZJf/7ZCJZugsvqeVREnTNSCW81CuL0cxyNLqkLYeXNNS2nj3DGbX7JVDmGgkYoA4BKL6kRkrAz6D8lZe00pK0Fl5ql9PLFANeYYh8BxG@t5KJuyXpPrn0DJSlGPiYXOiElywyvJRKJMR7yB@2kKVkDHjmDi0Ike1nTH5JiUYxD4mlBmbg@@TlSZS6zcuTJE3elZyxQLLbd5rblCrm1cSMzWpOQMe76HVYWeywnC2oDRd4bNsxMy/sAfWPJ/wKN@oz2l8kW/7BlzAZ8nTB4shplLmOkAlzy1dAwGEYiIivMSkSAWHy618HxRxjwnouE9aj69lUKRrKijBMh/F18Dno4cllwRTuLrfiN0zupHOf4hdSJ/GpfnR9dPQ2chlmBRYKbh4K4orwAc1zP@1aZekHLvbjr2BwORkIJpfFZ6vJ5MePH2HEAddFJVEB8cGvyEU8VL8IrzJWWV1djuXyy7HnoYYvW5FwOh05YYqSZJeKYbXb8NN7ZKg9HOTX@jqlBcN/@Gfcz0nfcbgvCOL4Br8R7kbKBtnlqiQtR1fSz7VSIp1K/@1fL97H7o4aa3/7O/2kvIiPQ3z87H4f3Sdi9rvFxe82NlZWYkBI7j56f/SuWq2ubMWyRxfZ9ZV4anHtP/2fi4vp9Fo6uVi3LLEeurh@K6RTK0Lib/8idHT0umFZQIgCXhkmghPvefiJLJtl1@wzXNcdhv/k/tz2uSV0Nzuf0doVjFfKJGxCoWwmdPIhNL/aFplYWV/9L394@CloByvp5LkJTzv4KZjLB7kTHPCWcd9ugpXgGoLl7oOjZLlcBufqf/n3EL/yEvBgyGgNbpWsiys3ClbiZYryJVjJgUNMpyHd//snPwkEK8Pg56AoisER/TXQDVf@mfiMoSMprOYFXX@OpuTxGvqucSmSopi@dOvTV91YtZ53D3BDvTLd5@fVu8dVzOEGcjwVrgK3Gl5/93/83R//3R/S3x/T7z@ihfLc4vOPW4zJ0APjVSw@n6mHvan340QcroTXOoL4GndKFsyXYw2eK4@Fgz7HFB28O3NI4r1/I1wg6JrZRTlUZ/vauC4ug2J@5fD5AxU03zhS0LuYk4xHUi9xNu3nVob3wlxZwL4FLhD8nu3zS9PgH37uK/qgxz76afymcQgXxvPmPsgO63Atwh/9w@W94n2RfBxvApm9Fn8D6RsIXgQv6vUdDf@an/Bv7zP@fbLx77SFf8ef8O/0M/4d2/h3ZOHffhP//DUTCK6trQWj0WNQGR2mfcp1Br9EouG8ecwbDAR/qxcLQHOoR@P39xeJD8NoqeT8gx5V8t7w4i7IUf0@Hl/7UIlGLyhnFxUni2vxlcPcIXter/Bc0z3R@LAG2KNrF2trZX2TfolGBa94/UPlYm0SB6GpV54/j2KTfQ4oKvWLi0DwDmuljLdlvLUsvKcFIUmvX1DCQ5ddCARR2y1wpbfAPehbG/gWCH68@xiOrkfXU2rqJiVei9f7@uH4//BwCAHKMHWlm6leqie2QWSylHyWGqVGw1RfPxTb4JThL9UHp5LqDFPdlJbSRHE0nED18H//ULf3D3XApkNMe5iyEXGqA8/u4eE@4OtA2lfwp6RSqSFkcpi6gf@UigKczPjR80MjcgfXx/uPl/eXgQsmfJRBT0iIoUQqlMiFQko9mzM@CbFQ4/IiVC8Fk9blZZJrUCy9UiI7jvf3jUbtYKvRSCJPLUWfR@PP4SpXomvOYz1YKa1fFuNYlW6lBpNr65eVTBzduSjUUhr9ot94jTHCs7J4GYAh4fk5/s5vb265ixzoujynq8GDz8@T3Ov23Llu4UrePIBgwsFAGf1H@m8f/tf1v3/GWPiiHoH73f1amK4I/kUid/d39869EgmHnZfwGvyhB7xjlLv7CjoJ6A5cF@FIPXJ/z/3gHo6scYQVTGOtQpHHgNBkgzzVy1CJMRg9hZ2Ft8vLYSoVKTXBx5uCl77QGk6kRLtblpq47gYjBnE5QiDZlVJpxXGv5kulvOMWc7lSadmDSsGL4wQg2ZJaJWT0UtCIYB44@4dTOPFCxnJD4bbcwa8mrBsGjP7EQurLF8@r0WgrZqOB/pkvXy6hJYVwc0u5kAWfVP7LF2iHoQiMDA90Z1m1AOM8MZkeo@9JlmTbZhjG/rHLEG5Msy5DEQxPp1IIjPFZdm0tt1Kp5FbAnctHIiVhie@MCXejBTFyv5QUeDFgzBYKOkFifjVCvvchDGfBNbZeARa38GJ390GiNlvJRsLNkRzxPMRCgfuwlVw4Hy04f@XFCEtWlpnzd3GRia4sry4/r9fHGghKidKdVBbvy3dSEecR7kstx1It7hyWnj3LFIAs@VTpMtBobFVPqw385AeuUYMUZuhJ8iaA64@GGbqgSZ9soX6BBalfhkLF0nNer/ksC4ZKDlw8BJKL5QtU3iCMLJUOHhkYAlbEGwgWxeV0ZjGZHX6Xq6VgRLSM18XFRT6djy6DXFsuFOr1OvmuUYyL/rBTJ2tl5fiFmMvW46jHXA07y0GDiauZ4HLAoJ1GqynWxsVaEyfQFsETqpQ1cV3dklXVNQx8q5tq@1Zpy4uB4NFedbN2GkuvAcr0dnUzlj452wiK@Jodv1NwBt@Pa9WtwzOIcLRXq57UXuy@qZ0dgT@aEYWrfyTJA7kh3w4Gt/jekOnaVCzp6koyjIYB17Dzwy9/94df/g8//PnPf/jz3/3hz//4V7/449@F31/C7@f8@fN/V8ji/Ve/@Bf/9oc/@3Pw/I/w@w/w@@tf/eJf/YT/6P1v4Pd/@fz@xvn54PgvALh@71e/@MO/@NUvfv9P4Pevnd@fzP7@4K/n//74pw//MN4f/tvHYX7@7@H3v3FcLuzP/4z74XMG/s843O//yQ9/9L/z///k/KHzz3/4o7/Bm/Pyuz//4ad/@MNPf@eHn/7sh5/@U2Cbf/irX@L/H/7VP/yHX@L///pv/uGv/qd/@L3/hRx/yh3/z7/@d/z@97/zu3//03/597/ziwfuv/vo/RdP8P/FP4LP0/P5FDxPKde3@vziR@XnN6HGOBXgAWCkf/7Dv/pnwEt/xN/@R3iDfy/oZ96LFxKlAWc8Ovb8GWNfkqDKpZ5/8UAB5f@MvuDNvkxiI9@U6/urX/zLv0DvCdh/5seQEmdhlxDYS@1n2Bi8jPlhf4bN6Ydf/uSHv/inP/zyT3/45e@hhI2vFGLVWFz8yigUALNPgEPA3FPgAFBcwyX8RbYYSINjcQ3nWQJi9ONHIOsiuGBUsBzIZuAtWK/TwOLyIlm5TF5W@FWH90Sygj6J5GUSwxNJGFQ02HcwIMPf8@fL7Lt4nD/HfgGxQqghj1HoaEQYvS3zaZMoDsbhNwysFOANJ1Ki0D9GeVAUgjairFwuRwPDMoQRKLxinCGr5HFYjwPBMuDFSDxOrJEHlZsNNwgLxCxHj1ljuTzkEaPoUSEMDDOEXseCmBai@fIWJFgebjHEhcijgY/w/Fiu5MvDCqL7nrIAOKIbkCRAlTF3w8r38F4mnAAfGG59D1nJl6PRSh58ylRUSi3WoDTFLBWOyh5lVG70h@E6PNafM/adIOYFPlKFmmEONN6jY@h1mrBZh/DL6LJTHPp3nfRbxvhQ7UOiD/fj4evoTfEdAMAbj@PuMfhBNQLAcwgeclRRShYeUY4BKBd15lM8D9JOooEo1W@UXiB9yMPTrrWK7wXRYXGWlpbAtVYRMsIhDHSYeV20bMnExRVS4IpMyBUE9MbNOPLSEQ2FlreW4S7Cf22RNtRyciwHlkKorISYm0Y8mtFX9CDl3i0alWWZch4luEBw7M@Vb1ohA615hUUCYbLlH6HxtGwY8Ny3uhv6EBTkmCDExByfA484w@13erFY/l5cWQ3Ak94H@BkBx6A9VAN@Wi6BjRUJWrmLr1HDBScoVLlApeKs8jExUDmpnUKE00MmplMJBlr13cpqeiW7kk1ncrnsalpcyRVWctl8BoReLpVNp8XCykohX1i9pyw9B8ERKy43s2uVfzJz/Xf/ZN413xevQOUtGyZY/D5QGcbjyTTluCxmV0ujMuSDvAIVUhX5@GF0F8fNnYFL2kx2h/uWIFuBuziy6QJcLLAQYAvgBRegxfUN5iy67x6WnNVH/EALX4EUxCwwQiRwCYzAsQWM6SuAFfcMpM0zkTuzubEzhc5TPDF4AGlANWhsD3d62jo71fmOwg25FVhzzrpVAgFarrkAotYD@AWEi3pgLemFzse02ePfLdw0dVDAfzzMhqRd86AthZ9y8oJ2JDRDZvUVu/cAxJnRx5M4svmPhqHWb0IGcVqWA2zAzVR1fR7AKjs7eqCU@94JZFz3pCPIAH68@2Ln1Pc8rVU3dwI5tnF4sDX1yDpAWbZX2z71Xld5qBs166F4V9vbm351HjiIWmTZ1VgM5CPc8Bmji56JpQ8uiJh4ZH4ZOqfkGlvqMBwnZ6HNsxxI4MtyRRp2tAGwOIwCkw2ZNcobF2IpWK/kV1azq7lUYZU9Pxj0B0gJ1h3kdw8ZCry3QmZVKArrglgQ19lZcbFk3tn3UiywjxvhCiI/0KFYgR0YhfXx@wZoG8MOmHIbRmS3Gp1VaeJXygYGe9ATHuiFTlPp9kD43eouQKApSQx@33pBfNl/2Y972DwN8psJUeeA49Kf0mGpQIIm69KFfDZfyKTzsXwhv5KFwWo2JqZj4mp@tZCKiSkxL@by2YIYy68UMisgJiE0W1gNBEGcKJ1kEnoBURDoqWgttEG8hsac9USvEgjyuQ7oesMS9PERFpSCDc93kGdCJn@ZgsgCfiXCsmm/77JSFvBTtyn8kCyglliLBbe3N1Pb24KwgS84S7mZEoQ2vmTzqdTqhiDIFLIJMj0tCDqPA0EAZvOXVGpjUxAGHAEeqBaEHr7UcqjPCoKCL5vV7W1M5wpf0hgfwK55CH9R3ZdVANPwJZMhhVgQPnnoAK7KE1qhnNbwBdPEkG0esglhgvDCzU8qBRiOORzHsOOWtVoVhF3@Uq1iyEsqeJZn9RW@VOkSBBNegBsFoQuOrinLmiA0wYk8KQgtcLVGEvih5Wc8e6vZkiCMOIGQRIIwJGipdS2ApuX4YzI7OztSz27LXX6NTP5sQdYgRBkOatvNFy@a3W7THFVrL44x5OXLHelqNDCb3aYTrdmAS4c4EHLdH01fkMfdRkNS54a8ghBtKqQxasiYt4b0CfLkXF1MpN94CSEvIWQ45@LY4OoDaBOvjT48N6QmhbgXhdBz2GwKJWRUe2TIODuEjYe2TcX6UsvUS/g@LC@GwqHY6CJdL5Ev64cjd6nSPQZ2wvTNGpSSkbvRxbCcqoPyLZZwkiq82EdJlRWKi9J6eIjuHEgvMb0iRIqLy8PwZawRWRfSoP4W8eM/eifEQnFxfZAXciDmluEJog4l3jCcCqUYg1sscrFaXxdWEamwvh4XLkR8BRgpvoIpoHxcRdWgdA@0sKGjag5sudEIh29l6ToSweyiNkH5Pj8/j9zxbWIjKqtS6oSHsWGZZ4eNIiUsjCnbA@inUjMo23jmeNCydZMj7gJhhuupIpUeMpMXIBvJZGQNxRMKFHh@PD/3TcN70/E@F78SrBjnX9UR87lIArefN/ROg75vwT76AFF5PMdDInRA1N1NRHqzVQycooZJ3@RkaMigiZ@xojO5MHThFlXoo1My6JuFQKDiqFx4JjmxPdCwaAn8sJZdckJO5aGd2JFxz0/L9dvkRzETtSF@e1LRNTfgZARaQz@xe5g40yypI5fu4ufxezoXjIc68Qy20mZSuQIuqR2mhJgUuaU8NyqVcqPcl/uGPYIRCinJFS8u9I5sg3FIPB7i7pCHnhSKkippaHGEOtalYXAYqLTxlPVGeeNuUCwC7H1JLsumqZtCUCh11rXygDJ4JJt4mGP3ELpsGU9NtHofL2sItwlUu7uPV0ymlbrlC0z3C97W4oJQj8cvvtRBFS6nSqOgVLYGTbJpwVJN0NVzpSH4iasrJRWKyk/ELNG@OKnUY81y88OwZJaNgSmXCPyLCv1ZI9GAdnSRThViaRF6LOjJIAh@q/C@Aj8Rfmn4rdYXF1lYDaeGqYQYE2UxZus1DYiTKhaRRkBceoWnFImml9VwW2fSWpxoDY2nhAlDA@4xQ4n1whDrWJZUDh6JflrPxdmKGCmFFyNlS/5U8tM/HCl1yuEPkdInILO5FG4nNiLrK6V2eIM1IuAB3TH80iy3wocCVDBjsVFO8UHBkjXoX6QWc2LsLt6I36uSZS@Jq@nixWDpIi5CuVJfumvC@4pQBwLfB2D84J84h768BH5us@K9/7j/HvsZJVDVVBmqQyykSw5IwHDaeFhgYfxQHN8dFg6FVtOhUCRUAqhF8CZREbmjBh0CeRN6JoKUgZ61KBTSED4WDTM54AOfnBgI3gfaimWwlUIgeBe4v7tfq7ga4is2GknRuPv6jLFuFIbASVrpSzSCbJFc8UTlOauWq93jaskBrW7SQDUZYJf8zGE8ufit64nRtcoH/rzEtWRIJsCJQ4vvybVoJXkZEARsIs46UDifjfAB8vdBMtXKNu86KCag0Rf3kVZS8YS@oHBRj3x/oKh3@Uy8QiMn4Jb7@2AUyobbSipJolTrkHZzBIKa7jhxacAGGQPiM5sVcBwtM@Ok8GH1Q/7D/tnh2eE2e54q5ot5ToZLPrSNiSExtMaegxanHNcCQeOLnhW/116WgkUjlFkJZSb08suyc9o@jDwQvsB1M/jVL2CAXI@Aq1wW18XVomI5y1rhojUwZDOyLubSxXRKjAStezwKnF4N0lPMrQbrQY5yZTUCblqQSYvBStLxFlcxVpy/AfNmg1bhSzCdygeC@f2PXxhzv2ytpMmVTDqZXbpfu4f/yv3F2hq7p/mBe/rHWxJu9xyA/jGC@0KP8TUBN4YZh9e/j6/x/zW6bR7ynAs5qIfgRxAIlvWh8aERDAQLIRjXhFg66@Rx6Iy4URdf1uhPtpbx78PYY9myrGXvDV6XocwsW4EB0XIymbyMvE6D3l4o5MR0MPDr2Su5vBBgywtVFuLG0HhHh6ZQveNmoYlvzeGkzvJCfOvkcPNV7RR7OlnDbwWzzcODBAbh52zH5wVbqiyZ6sj5nu0IobCDPN08YrrJzraOKM45nRQlX5q7cVJZ2m0XnY8@xW6YmMjgYmU2mVpJilkm5oup1WI6xyQQQxZahnBcSxiVUbE2dWPER1vhzQhFXqgiDIbtKTAWtuQie3G0RzHIaMTywlZt/5AdHuy9S7i@3P90Z/eEnRxun55Xj2tQjv3aCROqJ2z3RGDnu6c7h2enrHrwjkHwcfXgdLd2ggiSARRhqAVygnlDH7ZmjawkqogWjX8mvC29dS3bk/6SaUhJtO076a3hl35k/D7GpP9AU2Bw5R9anVQXuGLFEL3UbpsBPKKqtNgCDqYWlqHrxhOyvZS1yrKDt59TZnaRtVYOQquslTrQMmurTE05f0xd6WeO2eLi4qUmePLfXwxvZOf3wsMN4DfO0@772kI4t8KWYRSXXomMQw4OjxZS7tvC@fHpguiFHW8tpL2X3e2FjPdSg7cV7237fGsh671tVF8t5MbRDjYXVr23rdrmQt57AyZdKIxxHmwtiKmAS6wb0K4W6GuG4e3dvRpbBqBIaSIUZ9TQMeUNhAiDRsTthSDJ2fLybU@P0QChOZqCbstfg3bBJ6AWUCe7QLrWY2xZN@AG2h4AQ7SAp6NLZrcVc7CiHSzoWAJ3gQUs0AIWCOAX8KQ6wrHFMktHGAQvdPi@iTC3ixhjwplF51G/s9ga6tAVYIYYGdaic8kQQ3Y@axpYuHdQhjs069ihzdYEKkJOBVOIRPAw48HZ3h5PzCBVMiwQJON65RycugHYoIhwx6KDL68cXi1UF0irBUepwE@vBu4najMwXZtICijnwkILEExS90ZSYwyVqhguyiNefOGHJAAYgsGdAhc/xRkOt7CsXdluUYYiSMza4TYvIS7rl9lkLUcYJkqUomB@/OLLF@a@XdqTr@bkqxbiuB3kPFscH89pGWEj6LfgHp8lCDIVQDEXkGOiUYgNxaEwX7kWgOjw45YF3FxWIKFUiD17RvlYg7dCiJLAeFFKkcURBBE4BCPyITIva4uU3chCchk33ND2G7Ldiv0IN7XbHHlWUUCyTmd0qla9VuhV54IGQ8vSlEB2gjptrGtwZ9INeEfxCJwcY01oJjHmBoo5DMRhWIzJMdYB7ymZ2lA04FzZHMtElxWgMVLtH2zxGuImgMife1CJQe4VqcJAWDzD5kuMvrDQNGGkXXKhQB4SFPAtMk0YCcHhHo93vEXRlnl7QbbE2E@JubtddPmIxwZ2cDiNyIpWGzivOMUlz8oYaAa/gwzbbxnQc5bkyKJRB8LjMgesNgkXj3O4e5cvv1KI2nQpFr@5FCiWHyxF7YnF@M1KAd3amEWgFCDiw4A3CtB0m6zN9DwU0BcSCirNj0MBHeiYl6CNTyB4Qnzocsfx498eHzrp4nRThnYLNcilAo8y@dqafG1PvmLzBR@JwZggvcK@sCa6xBy48PQ@y4OjzWXlZMTO5CvN0pSZ7MbpeBKYpwA8h6KSgyEDzgpjlCAJCz8LIvXx41RlVt1u7B7UTidDEV/CajgZ79m6plIakUkwJ0MYboXxJeLlKNxBInB9M3zE04gRPRsnp8e16n4M8hdha@MWMK0DwM1pCRMluHdTAF9NbkF/3I6x8EmVLUfYM8xZjDlzBfjy5CRU3ZIB1YMptgdGmpJKcRDvfbIlBbFFBuYkJYRZOMK@XF5Cl5paZWLf@JLpZ7TVTJuNMquo7HI8ng7iSHlXwBzwpsmVDYRscxuQxbmJXaVSbMXMMFvugcY9TJmz@Klc99i3UbfonjE2dBqUWSWGR7pRtjgWWaBfnFRtHtciqW9EPkBfbMbgh905zexFST9H9qRQV8HieWnL35qXr2m0k3mJ87ysUaKzefi1MxsKw6XA1DlyMmyjG7Yh4VFrJ/CQ5lCP0MsMBPg0i8@@WVjHDwLZkSLZpUGZ0mig8ddGI2zJageYVR@YLejyUV22HDC8MDTBA6khoWMy0CEP6k@TAW0Fj0ajaU3odaYQouUR8EZrimFKMRDwcmbZskG58mUDp8nwS9n@BGGAPfEO1YpHFn05jhQdrXhbwvbgIruYMEnFcQysXmyON4jnWV@PTeeEeWwzJwwtD86L4h6lnxN2NejPywEIhgdCnMOwc0I0/XBeBG7RaRxQv/AR8MJP4Ho9HJlf9dCuJmvcZ5KL6H9qDmTHvtTuoY8FQbl0ONBX18EtGZi2peBnFqYRecfxIWZ4GPFZBvDYKjLmJMlqKco0eheTg4iOttKXBNiw2OoB1u/EdD4S8yH0YWxzU7MP4WQ@pJDDOUiC7IR4350AtTzUyILTeMfxE2jYQmvD8G4cQTcegcfQMSxWvgu8gDbJvBCPmec0uTG64izjkD/OuWP1ixPW2x6CdgshRvwE/U2Tj39r8nFf@tgmf1TSZXYxmY961PdeBI9xGd0G/qMScnM9mVrkm0rs5xpZvn6AfdHKji8Zbl1jMlkPjSOBPJ5yi0Lo0eOJQgJx@RF9g3yh6nPO/s@LPe5/lsssLnpxuMQbtwaaXPdlPoB2QRoNNKjbaJAlxUYDZ5YaDYGnQB0vdnj@TtdpbDwsAVpqQ6fQsBCXhJgQj1dPNnd344omxLjl@rJg2bopN9AgmhDDVeGyQAKrgTA9WTXKgrORT7IYxRYeTqPqSwMK@PVECIinsqtRImNLuV9PruUvkv6EIulTiY2tdz4htWNKDQ0VPJaSyc3guQltkqU2NH1nygoKGm6T3/nMPJo0mbCkgVP6ThZ4uhbN9Flov4RniR4N9HPqGg2B7Ck0qqbZPsG17CPMGOJxWjtO9SCCMady7hOO6MtdjKy8tWVHz6LpoYQwtvDpZCzhlNTH766Cxg2jjDu0SWs/Tn5j7tykhdOYU1kdCxbdwMJfCGgMCCrgSDfg7hkEArdnEgjcaBQIvVxRB260CIQxOo7DMQ4ELjIPBE9gb2FsjbQvDZX@ACdu/CYnHE1unC3s8rEk1OtT4KT04xRFiISKZp3DDt5IVCgKUHSLTBFNmyNC@HkWiSL1wKyQJfvZmE2f6jAP6VwbR5HYb6GSfIoYimbLyQ3EjQlM4EoIxRWLdRh8@njHFTGoPk/56XzWExFBSWJe/HF/5bNoVJ4YXiBFYPDAMzOOwGeZ/F/IJOU@UvRUkHGN@aG44jYn37gP98GM@zG4ilok8MhI6v834yR/lfxXOlT6/35QNDP0@UceyjwyhPnm0cpvcVjw3xT6/6bQ/wiF/remzT@gkk@jnG3xU@r6V9Xwb1e/SOaNoNswuzc49Zb@MXrYb0kRWP0mPcDN9YX4mC7w9f7ZRZP2d@s/spcO/Dp52s6db@vVavW0L5rHL6rdaq96jMajNlJ70fOrlY2t240XG@3q1lb3ZXfzQH6dr67sGa/e5t@96Hz@JIP2vnP48v1n1Wj1Am@Pjdtz@eg2I@et6mDwaXdnZO9snPU3T7LvVm9TNTXb2ZA/banW1v7p21enL7In0dtPL49efu6n@tZRJyUV@pmd/dybzdG5FsjeKGft7T3lsH/Srp2l@3tbyrvt6GZq76TwWkzt1W7fZzZvo9lUctd4dfji@OyqWXuvHu/uvWtvftKl3KfrW2M32S50Nq@O3wQOM6/FnU@Hh91auvBiJ3m71THaqfSOamav3h4fbZy92@m9kmr97exZ4e3V6CjXe/36xj6IdlfOc4N9ayWqVV@/Tr/SXtzc1I4DTUk/NTPyuf5aNG5vj/RCf1V@dbDT7b82RS15mH0TPemf3m7VNtRPq8PM2bvz17crJ@8G@69fvj9MKScnzZqUM5rt9MnV6Uqg1c/sRm/Oamd56UX7/HX/Zncn@24rud@TD6rtI/X6RXfnvX5ytLdbzVgDTdzbvFHfvehd7V9vbe6q@tG1qlVXkln1tP3u8DBw9lJpbsk7b62X1aveu2R243rlXbRtvDi9@ty7frlxcnaYTw@PRil90zpu7nSGW8e5dD7ZUj8df@7o@@LZ62ju5uplWnlX/WwHMp9H2cKe@k7uay@jre774Sc1GT0Txc33u5/fvTvZuTGbVe3s05vt4ytzv60dWoep45ev9pvqdd6@Mt5rJydiK/VCvt6PpqTA8GzHgjqST6Xs6ml/77Ux3NI/He@@t3Kfozfn1xl56/r4TfXTcap5qxlvNXNP6W@m2odS9Y1u1wbDF63Czdn1jrr36dB6F9ividnstt6xNjpvVgpvky@inesXbzfEk2HqQDvurOTMgzevzxWl1nt79vm4ld1@Y@T7ttZ9/fmsX4vW9oa9z3I@1VRP3l1rgbPsyfFR@lZ7pfTt7Z3j/Zx9mNp7c9TeGYnV17J4q61ujrJbQzOXOd96a7673tGM5Dvl0@AoJd9E2@8Me@W10uy03iit/qvAycve2cHRm9vdbM580deUjaN86mBvZ/Og2155NdrdH9T2mlftF7tv5bfGae46Xds4z229PcnYp9ev7ELrpp85ykdP1b7dPYsGXg56g9Wjc/PTm@H7lWq/KWeO1Xf6aFXsb7400sM31drh5@71kaEfiNvpUfJsT79WU59Pbz/vWLnqKJofntl93T4Vh1nxdSBz@9mwXxovX58cbrw8fP9SWlGUc@nq5E07lTnLJ5WemdnN5V6Ite1O/1O/IIuft/YzUqbfi1p718n2Zvvszfm1etV/1b9qBfIFq7Wx@34g6bVmWky92@jUsvLext6pKJ91X52sbB2kjt62j84@DU/bm28HZ28OlVTt6mVhr7vy9vhN4dXq@1PrVDrX374yDwLDfEa3xFwhe5s5KeQPe@ZJ5vyqYL9/dZXbUM@b4svddF/eVsy3@VH@2vjcu@3ensipZvfF1ifpuFMDSXp2lJKyg@uD4Ukg8@a0f7NqbETfXbdevdVENX@urCZPP10Vrnu9V7dbrZXz6udPUvbFlVw42U421e3si@jx5uujq@7W@ef8Sju1sfdGejus9ex3gdc7ytZV4fz6cDgSX2@fjPrVlKZmb07Oszen@sbJ@c5JvrffNDvNnaseyIb@6OzqdnCzI6/2hrf5V72rN1Jq721@U7NWjlKBl/Juv318@uptNdpJywX75vDdgXGePx9m9/P6eUE/zCuvqp0Xw9eHnVpq1VDOT4dntV5yY1Pp50GmHKln5ubh65335y@NVCCt5TY@b@rZ1U/Rm@G73HnyKLo3eNc6TffPTXPnrWJuv705evvqpLob3W2OXhxdS4fvatmTg81N62V0W8nJo53MrVXdzKgdPWD1N4YHQ9MoZN5f73WhJ9DbhfaL08y5ZlWrndvd/EmtWn1hNXdfSsPhi84q9BF41c7f6OXAr7lhwAC3CcgfEjc6Euhb3aY@BHnJzwUG6HBXgA53BfhxLtohzXcf/zq5HDj1H2Wg7zvzCZ5BE5Q11tZReUiwXc96L368I8b6OkRX0NXSDXoiWue8RhsHfCrcab4KTx7S1ynloaHqCn4XCb/RgGNSc/whuUTgUGP9EY43bbnPD1go@Gkjx9gufdaBf0GKjH0GFlot5n7DM0GmZL0ven4EBcLQunGyHdxl8Xiro0pdCxxqm1wfAyeebXtMQVUknPzAJMS9hiSmss7WVPruHmbuFL/IdPCCqTr/aIQ74pBAmRiR0RWcpCLDKzJ@589SbmR1RF8BkduJAN/x@aRdkH4/3N096UcGT6f2hoK6IZtTG0ANHtFdaU0uP0d7OM@Xk84SKypDDclsKjZ@RbrBj0o0eIrunjdjcu8hHQl2Fmi5YoSaDZkK5s6@NMS3qVhIMdplPj6hh/vpIEVQUd3dhsvLBqGkfVeMv/gwLxsP41b63d8W6gncbUWewKsDrQZAK1qQnlmz/86iTY4eUCnAF@trb3dPG86nYvgWw4lTUQ/suPRRueS@GSVeAl/@nZzPbsvEHQaQfZx25Ja2oag3OudlgfY94vZIqG0cYY93WyaAa2inAWIzaDfKxUqd7yBM0dY9l@BenGecE575cvVsTNAFZ0OFxwNPjMc3aHKQ2fIi4o4pywRAuzndkyFTm/1@y7z3QM00VUm7RleJb5WF8YLZ8lUWfQTDVw6cyvLK4uyf5AfioNwQ1dsGO86oYHrVQgDOhli3ms80bM603x7j8Br2ksb5MUzDG3Wpqt4Kj4OX3S03vGwRNyUOP5XUIc4kdnBnrW6OeEI4PRMulQAE9@mQTJA1d7eqr9TlMTUQHW3q8eUC@LbkeqH9AXmczxh7PLc8qUViB9oBND@rfDMQQl142arzpB6WhUDviL8wE1HHxHG3EIEzucxs3QAidByOg26MeITvTp2hCt/p5XER43S6SNXhn637X4p84y42KBmnPVGERLAZ4wh9KnNephG04jUdTGrMelRRuIMbq1AhXmQKjPDRnynR6EQ9@ZBfKEg3kUWJ2uE5oSCGvBI5pHdoTzC0Jw5qg2/FZR2@g4vTOjBFojVI6MsXr8HAq8eNR@4JTGAJ75v1yOCcM3lbdghact/dRui5KWRMFE@q3s/upaeTpzAA128NZSirYRCYDfwEjsHAy9myZBjcQRDe9iXwxsqmvDvyanExDLEuCC6Zr7NnLCyurYVX42Hy@i4fiXiN0Yme9kX3RQYhXamwcHo5nHEjr2BkQJmZRLAyH0GaI1hZDosugrSDQMwCBq5iEJLvWJ5z7STivA@xh7c@CYMf0pmT@nI6KtbX1vK4x9PnORU5PT/ry5loGiJz1AvRyRCOlgf4/OuTJQLkmbSvH/GhWIlmAAVPOjoZME51KsBL1J/mSn1u5/RbU17ccxpu50PR8XuesnmRx/Iip/JN6QYDt2Gbjid@U82gL6uN/ThLLyObg45ATRJS68l4aCrGv6zndFpAv9JUr@g7HEEQKAaICC4eJcauHuvrmt/e2SFwhyb4eJljTIyxPAxDQKKAxMhDZBAhRAOl22j1DQ8OuuJ8hO/45h0YJXKAK854fgDqCdV@NyUSY5x8uMIN@Jwvm1EfwukbhgiNvd0NfLypHeOO2d2DF1CFC1iOGBvf3WIucoxeETcljX9tRbEVyALINj6gccrKq2oyffR003ewucgd@GnsPCKVDiEYj@xoh8QXit1QdAcbJ6XLR7JNdKSPf3kA@UgJxhnsVmaSiuQY8Y8W5/k3wujQG8UmUoHDi@hkECmENDs9rh6cbB8e7xPljhrVvaOdKmKGAWZLMtuMvmKDDUTTZJV3qh49A9j9dvFz6Fgmqel@coV/KB5h@ecQOfEAsEEhDfKdzhGWlzP9DDz3nheBJIoHDUpFoy0bc3Dj3lUPzCmMNQchr0Wea6crdPI0ryekDm@2J3TlaAUlHdFSly0tZANj01d9JI3Lk6SLbwNGmfRJRGq5qEd1iV9M/g24TJo@DI18ZA0MXB2W24Kf/FKrJVtk8mBMfUApqx1KxJEsPkKBz/zSj@UHP5vi9b0ODvouJnW6KU/vHau5k8oiaI@cdj9Kx/UpSByLqyPduWolqUVOyvw71ROqozKpMj6UGE/tiqd2BalxgcuuphUypX5xNaGIzSOP4pLniuvGrmbG1RNvKznVXAcavdVDq0Q0F8KlDlUYVhOZ4NBHE7LumVtlz9xWPG6J85W7x5Uyh7CTGpnT4Yz7T2fA3G4D2cIzcxt0coVGXwMT65@/aPItvlBPyQ86uUMMgidOaYA67cK54hPPUD3IGYgJpCGdlrlwkqtTp@LhCzsIWdzNT8Sna9ApTGdWQNFAWowPpzllJVVSt5yBos8TxarTC5ttt5ET5LgzM9vTB7oQCH35gcPxqQR@jI8nlEcnfVOzTKiRQ8Y6KwVwXTUehwgRPq9BOg2IWywDZU@x5xcjP1sMp3CuTqbwEzAo6hy3yEUBgn6BcQ/4uomX5pbbVw73MBxGjvgKlio5JyjcE71nRywjZjK@47@H5wcslxufDkZTZ2wlnRofOUajZyxXCPyoebLxfALnR2w4ToUiWyHP4NAddEFZVaER80dbwa4f88aHxUP@GJU85WqZj2AtRxw7XYPF@gMLpyjxq/S4XmszcSgmAgsgFGkO2Pncp9t5A2B3IJmSZsv8jCUKcmdlFxOkiKjDyiaUqwktA7eNocTHj9VDt2DKfAIYfNp6izZJIg6KBzU96NNupBgqDDeyiWYAFNs56L9AMsdhBy4aKpwJXE9XOFRc3uAkdEQCtWicZOFkpG4ZqcenXhxXmtSV070U5fJ0T6Quzf1yMGaAyOuwCtGYuwMLDoFnuhkajy87n09zm6QHPBb986YGZzsZPjh1x@EOGt7HzI78lfqcyRjirpa/Dxo6m5gIFZWpHnHPwJEEcI9Atdx5CA5Ej2GduifCxUejSEEYv7QVPhfOSEaQFkG9FHUpJnId7tJxjN1R8IL37XTi5zK0voizM2DkHJjzjkc6EMjyEQ7hnI2chsD2ySGGfhyQC95Ql5Pj/QdDxOGdd0PxTRzijsLRHXHGBYiAj2tJ7eL552fS5pfCaaOUKD@SNp1TCor42vJ8MF5kBwxL5wODTJE8cgvlgp0djc@9uYCUe5qQeizzE6k9NfNOcjNAE5R4YtY9Qtw7c3XzkELkvn4j80UqZ1uNo2b66ocrSVCJDiMQz1K7d6YqHBq4UoHnrumLwXVmN44rSSjEOfQ7K3IcKM@xnHaPA7sC3ZvmHJ/rnVdQzsluUd1iUg3S98tVxaCucbKsTrPwlzUuzhZ21VdY95TxRGGdSG45Z@07aODoqPott7@AHYrgnFwWvmvH2HdtXAxxfPx9lEuNefJv8qyzr0F@KI9bpFc@L690aNZ74W3VWTtE0e7nd4yHeFNuI8cPWFMXICK4rpXczfU81sKCo86A0jMRLx1xpp09dnZRdDogr2mrPhq33Uu7mMYcQ1jK7HuOh7qgz7I5AeyCfSE5jxmIeLAdBUrqg/VxkSOZJxqpyx0YEI06/Vl5YjZ4fID6QUb0Y3Fkp@@I8qPxSabM5mKEYbybnI/DjeJ09@P2X/JnZPRgRpActEbk9HXemhE3iXD/m66MjnU3w9HcQO8y0nD75Chijv6WTbl6QNgY6wve6ICPB/y6gaNou8ogTmyBAg9jY340OsYg9QfhxxZGPvEFPjyaBzHJAog/Gpma8AsknsO0b1hk@AYxs9mk2iGKGrxOJvNNFUkTIR52XoxnxgUiS6bjuAzInVFxplQT6BgdcqbZuBI3/kGqLBomp3Gq3/oHVvwyFh6XLMfjLAMPB7u7HQiF0jdUmZ/cEfca1cNdz7QV69m2UUwmZUtHLyuhm93krXKtJDlg4MQxWxWXB9jO0UgVD2nUzqArQ4NTdoKdyHyzAuq9qJZ9pOGkPIh8xEhoAUsD4E4HNF6tJeNXW@xb3D/gILAS/sxCsGSBHq5rbKTrzXHuJedkDs9AjPJuQea7QJhBMwEZSLYk25JHchIjJpsq3PoSmphOwpA8iSVMHmryHsQ@gSYhJ66kGymw5csYnZyeSpWs0AXiOHdEITZ@8Jx2j@Acgo37IllTh7rx9qc6gwSyIqlr6ohpaAKgC5huEBqkCiSFnHcLxaQdt86iDm15kGkcsZIq5EjYW04PR/Gw/04kICwbCfCP9RbxfIelI7uYMu1NpegTe1qm9mTwhjm5iYKP8yf9Wmic6@v7NLwtHsmkL66uPWXfx7w9HmT/C8j@0M6PZBKnRw1VGjHhViLj3mxzZTWVK@JYS@lqxIbYWtCIjk9jl4cGfvIWNwZgP@7GVeUbWWUZrMY3ijUAwBN7AEUKBA1T6vYlFzCcKTJMxmeji8bXEyf6x0G6rk76dPDcBBuPqPFkGmPiGBud4HJ6FSSm4@30C3IEpBbc1nHLs64brAiOttwcdKkzwHNZbgw8HSXFmhhBilTCzcg6PIvwhKyT2Whox9j4y579KtxPpCvsApp5nbkLFEIpQKWApl/muS@58bHnQDDfig502HxVA3qEZdZwBqN8lgCgsQ8LcziLz3vS4rkL0tZ3D3HWhhLkm4vdECyi4dh6fHBPyTLz7SkBkYD2ppAxyQRWMunOjISq@PFi92UjxENp1ijM3eMpIt7rLXvkcPcvdPjukzWyCcbIhieRM1Jyd9WLJXbvAuIeENRwcGdJPOTuHEAN08S1mfGOFCC94I7CHkPry0DmK5BUcchm2C/5isE3eNf5bJejgkwHi3V3DQv8y6mSSw3@rXOv/seLWc94bS5QwRfpy@l3zFGnhRZfiKFVEmeBaSKv2Hk5PELcwXE5XXyY8wN5THKDM5tIk6Yxb0KVZ5TPuYKwQJ0zTl1KjA1ZF2ff@fApxkbOKxqsD3Cr1KnYqCyWPNPVsjbo3@FgJMajDIwYAt8zGaR9KYB3Z0Rn8sS91g29BIl1FOQBEhTodeH649TGXSrGxPsSpdyib5hxEQ96xCzvz92LdakhvuIFDEXov867ieJ3bSHG08MlA3KIriNdj41T40T0cj0c6dfhYWwEooPheaSKM@pAtzM5T68jXxDZKHHWaRwBg/OwDQnXHRtIu7BrgYw1hmUYIDVGZZzD4/a/UOHlzYIMyCB8kQFgPI6AMEJlrrJL4URmEH3DaBTDYVA3GT4wijjKduPPhGPtEX4e34//fmwkj@jQGMYao4i7LwViNEbLRAJve8r9THEpe79BeWfyO1XeGXp45X2AHl55Z@n5o8rrzRi/pYJAF0MPHOPgkH0dRtQA7XnyeYp1hp6pcQ@19W469sDALxFNxaYPSczG1g1Dt9CG@fwc8DTnZILCff6Q5jpPowhuGCAn@fSRmE9B08NPAlgB3sRNHfXFMLnxW5S8/wJ9UuVz204fTR6IuUAz@t5rfOodEog4XYnfyxWJXvkwKS5TuToBats17S8uM19SJS/jVFA@BmMU2St9hPFXHw5f0Wn7IuTGjYKEirB5UQaod2C86SjoNz@KQ3VHPk7GQqqzubHcSsTYzu5KVxMisSPs8lHSWOsWfGtNDZLOwK4@fcIbx3rzvcOoy@C8MmimNxR1e2kYiu12aLZtk2/EZkfO7BQeewIV3u6Z@qDbY2goCnVAhOVbyjs6aveoXYJWjx8gHaCtmqK7LS48Lr43f5xkZwaDQT6dn8eWu3/ENlHxb45wLpnPBYR93YSzw2phwdWdFsZT2gsk6T3gOp/o4zMO4@SpznwZ2EJ@gCzs40wcJH9M7DQnYbcTi4ueBiJIto1G9VGzVngRsPjjaAYuw4wjogbg2vgiZWXBA52fWc7GvtxS7vzZ3QNWmZfb1NxM0jHU6Uw2ZZzqSz2SOT6LOD13A9nB1DE3W/I/Qv15qfLVaxj3f4U1IVGXK2MEJ8MgFzdHg7KDR/P6aIAcLWtwToUROKA80E0cG45iczHf4nwctS7pFsZeNFRGuGjCyU4PxrM3uNFobmxacetJUFV0dAARQQ5IteJrZ7hehl99w9j7NBz1IvMBsEWqHNqd5dnQW7jK7EaepYSpt2S5baHKKiGvUD7DeLzBaa7uKmFbkbo4QoSRuit63ezQfDSNFntKi5/K2DzCrJjyp8H/2963LceRXAc@s78i2eBMV6PvIMgB0SwMSALUYJckuCCokQLEQH2pBopsdLW6qonuAaFY731jNxxhW5ZtrS@xu5Z3w37ddfgSsfvg99E/@Av8B/K5ZVZWdRUAUqNR2DFUaNCVefLk7WTmyZPn4k/4so2tqcNckt4PkMKjE6/3hmAxxlGMveaPajBso6gWDFT4w2lngiKHYKIqpbAgezyfNHuiiZPmo2SDaieAifLcRSbEAkb2E11BpshKy@tQVKP3PFLWwVAcpVACYYjMCMfWlv2g1KSuYL8yAhk4nodioeuHhMe6flfVYDrEvTgY1zEPd8JkZ@0vZCy7N112YpjopvWRAOKNNZlrYRQ1lInB4NAxLicx7zRXg99bgMaqcoBrDG3uWNb4mkGDoUyMW@J5h4yCYvkFZJP83EF6CzXMAHUtJp5cIbBMs1ylShbR0lG8iHUUjGo2ZgZbRAxwCFa@7vy539D8KWSARrj3wAaD5u8oYex1UFhJTZfbJ6x06iUSsnQF9oHT6TDqjLxgGg7nv2pCKNygYJ7CO0PSnD6/L59JdhyvYXw7a2AwALXT2CV1N9RNwIs6bN4rT9Yxp7gvWw1O3Gkg56waihlMWNXRefCZyNnHvCeSh4ej1glI5aDLBJT0oJpARDZeVVYbgK2TzMVGUZ3KaQW7Ti@a0iZ6EqByBeqUTlEehDoeEzQRoynBDRv7gsiDsTfhyoDa5sFU6fMZ6DV29QkbZOxr04dK5egj/Lg3Y7eQ7vkgATyI20KFKofHnlUGtl9oOICT7AjarY@3ricyCjzc@HULQ3ViDVQt/EXcPtvAxRV@cG38CocyX6wScafKNdGtACw2S0rGevbOTbnfl/VFP6X/RCyzlnVpWCYo0e3HlwTSqlgUy@kLrN8mRQvHd1FT4z5aWMC6BNAD//Cmi28trLVBsjOcxTMgEK8z6Z1Al2C@fCSYaELj1Pf7NGxwh0Oxt3FlHipAjyGMysxAj6anXXRJM6DxMmaa9O6BQnIAcWLUZao5Nr30aYfzK0DPr1DVk@TH/bJZW1wV3Uvw8gOARo6EJ6i0ieSXMjD4HWs2mdEZOPKJopAVHBb8PpBEdFMi/ugXslYOted6c@Vbaacxti7BWI6FZymTMBR4RZaK01kwecMvRyh2o50/6vgk98a3QFZYxkJaooeP/GGcxy8ZWjgXhzWh9YwHy0knulrIq6kpgk1xyAY9bDgVDzC/4bVjpWWjjdxk2oItrMcSqIZkoWYUl@WXS97YDfHoN1eWIbJtUNM23ZKxdu2lwHMtoky2a5sMB8JdJWhDIIUiEFq3HMXvIpLUddQIDUFx4/mOQ42vuBqsLeZONTvlAq//3E49fEIr3mijqVcj04frMnXEdRgl4Z6lqruszRtYnywx/BRW1zUBHD5s3GjHYHFqW81Ev4ssrWas4XUjdf9W3OMDZElv3Ji/z@jQWBg18VgmXyRqlmVA9w6jDLjCtJG65emNccBLP8NURZQ8OdwBHO8KgymI@QZ82sLwMCqb53pZoGFUDyOiHeukr/HuA/Sdte46wzAQV2Z0sHKhkN4L3@8lRq9Arl7WXXc6wKbgSz@UiQ1UFq1Tbg7MlkOqufzgzyNF4KR3OEUcvP7LlragdqjPVisARSYr8sIvBQ@0TBzRixr1QGRk3AO1fCTVSh@0CyPsBD14W@5s6Fb1nYl3DH/2fGxRPywhv2RevuuFLRYmPt/deba/vXe0t/3d7b0X21SSFPmNQfF03CBJWXiGzr1HgrcUJhziFD6f@HCO44lDcZbwBv6iF0SRegzXXQ@u4286ULIz9Qq5b@4rT/LzXobeZJ3L7zMzT8b3pGkc@mgiNEVVJejfGV/A@XnYCctM/HAGkkMq1HodoicDjgtVwD0TNnPOwf0TV1I3oODRBCGWDXikBIPoDDlAuU0k35jhpBn2YTV7ddGx1dAocoj9JRiHCMgAQD5q3c7rFMLcXqsw8B7wnMhGYls5BDHcvR811XOudouqVVvcL@QhO8NgdFwQ7wlWC4hzg0OrigHS1/UQk1EQVIF6C@gpEEeae8QdauD9oNGqNxtfn0uD@BH71@St4ANM8j/QznvRTj8zflKW2b6OAWDxOBcpG7pE2KRMC7rsaE1Jg7pURStS0YeZk@dbkwv6279mC/IcA3Jp3eo3YzT@9dpzX9vM@pf2sfDNm@FkEnDCKkeTb6aK6cXXZ7DzT8Vq5P3MRa6yovjWdCLbdEICqr2P8URpuUTax8h57OyywB5FTUb8E2rtbglnlOLJ9K6VULQ1EWySSvNxPBrRRL6eEn1Cgz6hVv4rU4fP72uGLUDc3Wy14/fotWUckeho87004U2gnitU3G1t/YtE@3W9tto@qrRP5sh7xoI0XHPS3KSKNO02796phBo4W7qwji@Rv2iYG/MW7VTeEsZpZXQ5O7TMjEum1N9ZKJhR2gR5iyRGFofXSoaYE2q1bRIFrtlOKMTLPaqscV0sjl9KbT0ewVhYSk7EbCG@tNVZxrHBQFR0NqDtQTk9RwmUsTA2D2VyavRc5FUmC23BJsS8wP9zsbYyJMgGHt8aWf0ajay@tRr51mrkW6uRy6xGlm42puGk0fVHDWDNhqp2Btx/YQkW1Nau@vyzB/tq/7Nt9fjlo3@pvr/7Un3@4Bmk7KrnLx8@2Xmk4P/bz15sKypg/n3Xm6DKvYKp3/J6HknnV5rNVUWYFwKUr6oXnVP1WdDz3gLx3A87p5sn/FEfedEGl9p@603mAT8HjVGZJRKrCZIV8VuTljihxXUXKPkU3xG1L09sI3nzDFmyRLYXFA7dGHDz2x7xIKTHRc9KxmgD4ANIBTQdfpIl3Wl8WiempV9XMnDm33uPIDCFT1@oB8@2MNLn1s7@zu6zF@rx7h58Pv8@utlRWzvoNubhS8wiwKe7WzuPdx49oARuQLOuULZGBuuXNaGO4DQqvTeDKYYHG@KtUL4SXr2XCoVRoK0iQlWajmL3PX0gKXx3Z2enbXLR7tx6sPed7yJX4/1QFYsY5NJyqC4WCLeaaDQCtUkU7TY7U0fWstbiDel0rm5hdrtAMiD6XVUaeZneiX1PFR@hGBEfpCluNjNsGjVUdBNwIyrtCNZVFIGhVKreJ5QbUBtJD3RtKFgd6A8suimOWfEeuaS9tIaEFIMz7ox6HEZXJwDds1Y3VRtNGAAFQpLAACiDwYSo88bbQSGJuiMQ0wgv/pBwlxNen44fnyHXiAaukvCQA4GsSZt43mhKMcBRxx/xPCbMmnh3oBgpVCQkeHSSMxxqkSupxAH/L29s@CoLkEXYBQewsvWlIn52A2qAvf2kM4hC5bhllAbDFcQb@aypdTzswHWP5MITNFh6i2oEVO2ai/82tKN6zXBSIE59henOVbIdptyWHPzedctByYcLNaLeHnUaFaYk/tOVDXi40IAPQQOIavZ@gW6FxhExtoQmGAgpO2EAFAlXPvWjZFSjoD/teYkCctdxXvtfflmWQa7GRSwVH2qd0bDDUA/4EHKGPqjIzQVcYkhT8gRfo3gOnWQP4rfhU1SGmGADf6AHV2qzLw@6RtHEkUqRn8@ptdshY7grayWKZ91gs32Njc8oev4O2SyPnkm6eE02t7kQ/TmjEgN6dpqgm5eBQsWieUQt4eAOhXjv@JEKGwdfrLkbWw9f1X70g@pho3HM20Knz48XrJTIzyx0JYflYXQnSRtQrzRBWginXSyt9Rl5t8RVrpEB43LiA/O9edQ2eSxWXUwfUbysZDolvnvncqka2ZsQCWEkmXh3q6oDXWWVyhyqsiCI905oLHrW1SlVwmn2602Ma4@z0IYRGeE@Quo1dlg10q@xvF3jgx7sLAXh03i6Df6yjkUuFEX/HHs@Gl84D93KRrmhoWgxmeF09BZd1ZhbZenVBU4vnVcL6LYuRwf79/XRrV3aOj4e3gvb1qXY3qtttUo@Lj6WLFzXR/ujS9Dy4fZBaKHv1XzEfEguYjOUboizemtJ0/wVNf5gYe5o7QEaPHsxoqpBatU2HQ3RQ5zDQnFoGhUo22hihujF/tb23p4qbqOUbR3Kwr7XGfXIvhS3QcR9U3s6Yjtk2uzqhmkyYYIM86RTLti8NFntZYs5c/BytgrhQaoyHmazMFF74WYyE@sIPlmIhUDDa94Q9cglW3eu96DwQBBfHKAmlIonzepgIbObS3z4sJN92mTicasybxy@8ceGmfFm4qyLRNWTuY1IM8J4HHSO8eU7e/4@Z/54XdfDDJb3wyl1GJXwe@gvX72Aisf4UlxPzuAl06KnlHRWiEqX9NiRWV6Sw/7lCcrEYr8QXtja1oU5lqYxf3zLimRH/OkmvvPPJbN3KvJOvcVTyn17QsvxoeckjyBgMuEarDZtqoDihxdyhNFomHPSNQy5vdZuUWsOdCspmpngbucDfQQc/J276e0hXRXstpdWVft6quJTIlGTFXdrsQadCZjv3rlz@yrc6V7o4rVfFjefIen9Mzodv@1YKMN5SKpCQLk7z6o6PyaAS4bOhVtg39ELJlUQWJ2MMyXRdzqM7PZBW84maIsHjdl9uV9FeVG61rKapdqWjZ1PJBs7gSz0wVrCpqO8ahZG/@Ly6h5SULcr6rv5/vXxYkMglIdf/ILDZO4FY9wqgRGfHLFXVLiSr4eoFRdhCQ4@aDz9WjEwN3UcywOON7fJL9xoI801bkbBG9Tr15EzJbZZEZ@h6qed8fk7FHC9I5Ep56FNgJT1q2rzNeuocGTNzX5ASgQDE8pyk1uZTINt/u2RHXxzHdUHKY8BrAdM1wxg6eOSgnvPOkoVdKjJUoXTgD8xSTVOAlqN8O5h0pc5He0S/PFwbtIbnN73MPCcSb0vWM46JuJlaUMg0xEyS0UBJlmtP5gf0bCb7E85G9gYk/SRNAbulsPApN7kVNSp0kkHUnYaJx1yEtykTNKSQOHB5Ec2LYWe9@aIJlmizQHCUlWN/OFhXfSnPnXk7lgWE46IJxLKe6N@gSaFYp4aVPpI2ETXskJCB5v@YZ0UKGUDwjtZPLG8kDb9uIANDOlW6EsmKi5GDcD/SiOkqTbxYs0Hm6@Rwide2Jt6anuGd3wdG1FTJTkGWVLbz7bU7mO1t/t8O4kaW3yEPAqV0gp7FIpZGkbd0Uu2ChMeTKOTI07Un@ncM49zNQr@NkCjYGIB8Wc6V1dAKA5xWarzd/136gAO77GZFKdfPpRJ1z02faj3gukoOn83e0fTOwNOrw4k8Km6qKOQ4NOFYZGVKBy2Jgd6i8OwkMhXHmm3CnEtlEK1zMQ3RyAW16k1X74QbAWzf8LUwcqkTToOyAnbJO4EAbI86xLfEoajdxIH3KS3bFc5TrpheCjV6wvJFfWJCdzo2RF3k5Vds5JKXiX34kqYwgyeeohxROPayqofqHf@O11ZfKjg0b@Wvu2Y0UbfzTKN1hFDyy4B0zy0svlVwupzv5D8tbDgZAZVMt6ovG7wgsAg7/Fu7jKNJ8CIvhfAzOagwXgBLcDRKkgA8jJZAKTyixiPslsZL72MItktjtfjYnNyaonRZRTJriVudHIq4rWemo1eANwZByTBH0dwEbTO18yZA7JZqDhvsap0QSFFus4ccZ0O/yln1KG3aYYAejzUP1uHbHqjSnaxS@GTI2K3QDpvDQjuQeROBY81O72VTrePJLVhFU9DWI1KAQPO1El19VywJ5FE0hlaavGyIqMtiQaOvJYcjbDlHFqgREI5oLUkKK@aGBZAEYS4ODxZLFBeiUnQSjaoRfwEb2NNtdVajQa0kg1qrY8FrLUsrEnQShp0YV@jjTI59oahXXYun7xyDh9ro7Oq8mZebxrxSaOdVsAaimB52IyWQPf9Yz/6VMWMFv2qQ3uQaFfXxCO2ToML/p1PDOtDBTSrbTdBqo0R4m5h8VJ@RsUsjrLZt5gxN8xjAp5DXOP7uAV6QBD2NCj2wCQN0UyGXGj0KaZZMXtouNQsUm0yRlJFtXQOnxfI/R4snfN1hyO/F6vF8kWRm9VO7KLQJ50s96P79/VY1KPgyFeZ/9rSeMIRjFUSRz1OuuRfAsc0Mqko4qgOgx4LO6uIq60vaweQjhdwethJ4cDXlMW@6IKA5vDqduCDyiIObEJFXdYpG4e@VC3iWL42Dn1hW8RRu3476D6V1ZePro2DL4JZOBrXxoEUuDimxaVzQHDB/y1mkVpiPNAsSlI71W6SNAzOTuKrm@6LvqoqtBckDAn4Weorqx3CmNu0PrSuQdcaD7x0LI6H4/NK2oCjmHbuJguYW1iyvLBe@HJLqSyBtVZeW90Koz4cBPXB0KzvjMWfuqKnhCSCkOQeeImp904mcEXC2azL7UMzIIQT2n90hKpZR0ckGXq@t/udvQdPj549eIqXqCXeo1B8g9oypK7TrK9gPHuWthyRTpGrUNUCu1GgfdjKo/YJmm06RShyLJZaOrfgLorMQGFNLsmL6iPvTD2GLApav4ATIetGNgPT41AbzKZerL0tlmNI@wTTvZL72ga0hGCYTqQlBGMlF6zLFpd/NWINlVejVxEDdtUB22SGh3Z7X6HhklVQqdrbV9F3vUkXdUlqxmkpzyKq4OPdjZxTocqFSNBjDNYE/qLRUA@1U1yxX@sMe@jydjogx7en/rBz2u136uOTcWEQuuKexikNQnRyWUBlqp397b0XR88xTtf2I7KcwH9tytvfebq9@3Ifc15A1m1J3t7b2907IgX1vZfP99FjaCqpaAMKlhhMEhJAz3Y/e/DEguHvojSSDUJCuG/CH3HlU1X@@GhG/52TmUeVVSGOKAgPmalgUUqrqsg/9YKpDt6G/if0AV9FyxN8lIG6dFRjckjjoPhT8mJfpxcWFLVjMh1HBEoa8E5qJMrJEgxzGh5jAfJFFALfTtr0dZYoYx4a8gVjJ1UWDWSwWEHsuwYhrQ5cJi/mo56j0Ykjz@q5NwJIfG0qTaNBba10UUavkmNSGkoXLjXg5GiQc9RSdkkZQdFKL1hBjGyxa7ugDd4BiixKaBJiyxQqwC@IbVWp@OXzgh0gSrJgV@X4UefKsqFPwkj8mhvWHLFbU9bzhfqRQMwvscAxNMKfz@1HKSIweZ8iY44DtDw3Y0Z/dWdZwuyY2XHofSq2666j9sgjaPCDyGFHL@SzL6Y7ee6SBhxhRnrGk3mAXt7GpMNUIdN4GLVhoKLJXLEFYRiZ4YKeH@J/Z@LatYcKNA4QXNmGLRY5l91RopFQGDEAXfOKG8X12I0NmyUYxWGGuG9DtLIgvrAhVrIg3toQt7Mgvvoxg/gDp1LRk7ehVu7cYW3mxHxmFP8/pnitpmHva1XouDDgs4vr05iRbDMOga64aA5qn9mA3G7Z3UtblkT91f8F3DYuKVWjSrjhlzT7Esw//zfFdZbQXWOUfp97aG1QyJzIkxebMKO88JGQuG6S2JKmsf3VJdiKRT2L2WX/IKaIL3KI5qu/TsBkk81P9LwrM376hetGXLYVWzWkEfzlIgL3fRAccXm9vsjbKBvwYvbKusGiexAjYJDbNshKGiSryneXVtm08bUyq2zZIM3rVPnV30qdcn5lQPyxgaC9VgYzE/T/JRYaqeZDoSzQkCHRpuZ5/OqbC36cbINdLAv8eYydihxe3u6f/0a63XHJTPh/m0mcVMCmLz3tmQP/P6@L43Yujh8wilotd9xKDFGp5EJ89bO4HTy86WV22SL5@b@/unQzv/S/jkvHx/yGPriZa9DI0lugUQ9KZlLRA4ON5w8GwKRktMY6Rs2as5YcnsViMJbsQMtki8VZMntFZ88zs2@b7BTyC2awNJeE/vWIMbrPEQaJNYp/k5UvM1w6c8O1ubYyd8jmdplZFwNzGBvD44gpjsX0bKQuHMuJS8YiasktC7N3USAuuJ15@Qk7k87JqIMBWsNgVJcIIH7Q2D4NXvt4UE0a6Oai/jrMuw39Mqw1IaB7nIvX1weoUAFNFacirPvN93YE7PR609PpEN/QXLlXoWOkRgNdxtFFcDQ9DQUnnrgPp/4QeuAipxaziHDNG0Mr6RQGVvpa1aeqzqp2scpGg/XG6@SGjpKobb2JP46oMnfxLoAun4hBhSr8@xasZuHRQP2cELErWlf688QfeY4Fj1Fc/aqVQH4RKi6XahNlpMfEwlFFDZBn09MEhnOZcdKNcTmnHqLFj9OsruDIeUg3auJhhBBjHeGHakV80JFrGUQiFkSTJJaV6mqZR4kQPQfyPE1CrFZXmljRGLPIRRF5hjaa5Z0BuS0io1bCQdgMNM0CcIQxehnXjSb0DjJMu9ziP/zJj/97sXzeaOg0iqnjjzpwZ6CIJDFW/NwPnutvCz3eT8RWMYX7f8S4GXXf6/mnHYxQE1mogbhyMMMEIuZzIDR0WhUMYb8Jjh3LF4yuEAmr0XiwtaX2P9vb/RytoViIQFSQKo5EsK6KFR52KpnIF8VgBBFKWIR5KhUjkG7EIpTpFYKZHpN7nYFjaWDBaP3Wf6TRIll@gJruvC5TCDG7yE59UE6IurU2WjMRmoJxHn7rPzDmYMzas9mIg3FRCBN@jj0gfi2KdBb6xRDZ9f39H/4Xqk4sSoDnQ7nKqV11HtNPuQcikCWarbUOc3uVqIYGIRfxlUP0O39GyEIO0q03wsINe1c0SLK7/ce/qwgHPj7A7FklVQJP5UpEP2FE5vWARi4XX@1KfL/H@Po@vQLYiLrzZBefwjlZn6DRkGMlN64Yvr//Q2kxwPsRvplcUsdyormFzMn4C3tmqaxMR978WvhzZ/iPbKRi5pqHkQ@qTDw//tt4mdrdZNfJTN83rNWZalpmh3/8N1nURzrmsHrQAzijtacqc63ktPk3f9vgnxVuzK4gmH/4k5/@LO7jLLdns9z@/DReTbPFXszy2n4jtSV9D4@MYmWWOxV/nawmsXJnrvWZh@Cv8sZ9lhzsWd6SB9I3i352xbLPQ/ITjcQs@NmVSz4P1@9pXJmLPd2tnOU@y13mGnvOQk/hX85pJizGP7cX4@yymc9d8/lk8d8IOTJ8aDy6MC2NhnA4TWJt76sW/UXPvPh3I90ae/dDUVvMuLjAUQE6vDUlaA@hZvftlX@ejil/wXxNnNoSZwu6R1YtLakFriadYZhRlet@bXWt4NDBdS@jlo0Pq6Rw0WiMPDa6n477eOug97tTunlM6PkPgwdk74y/QXMJ3DZcV9jahtwTHFCTD@kFJ1wgH0RHPof0VQM9QPfhukF/75vu1lqcQveNG2ksw4BZohskTserUO5FRG4SldZh5qWC76mZC@F/mR2Ib1ddvl3hYEkfyY9snHPl5v07PzM7khmlIIk9hbJyNc4/lWkgFSN6KyePHcLT5aN2E1/mIpVM1UdA7tH9v@3dIlVdPi9pgeVh/oP/ZA46L0Rd1j70B01eyeM/BsfEgck9Aa39k38SAqe8HG8ZuTX/Zz3xIe9QeZXjSXaNenKq@bN/V0TSzh4kzm5ffckSjLl3LLXzTL18sb2ndl/uP3@5jwIZ2zGiuYPnX/T42s37Ml1gk0KChbtsG675K3ydtfKYvPyqX1kpU/f/60@x@4y24habRWuYLi33R4lyLV3ukjGiqbj2CMn4LJRnoQW0juuW3rrumowQXKB3RhGu19CDHwLGggl2@CxnG5M/m0zbt26pmPFcY@q/zm5Zwph8YQIedTgBbkvh/LnNbynjm6EMElnN8fXOzXrNY/zQC@3yk0C/aQpKSDazBb5nZ2f1AYanmk78uheie6IQHcM1xsfALIwCEmqi22wgPL8Hd1t0XjjtvYl/1Xqd0dtOiAoyn85QJdq99/Gc/xbyZMTj41MOxfGhcmKlSNpbnVd7VUBW7fbeVAdn/bZksGGwUTjhROR@JvrjNNS//PHAQAQRytlNVnf4phcMidstdodwkBXjqrmHGnKuP@V77LNhjBYiz8X7qSKm2WFFCoWPBpQDP4Gr0tbF/uxgfpgoPjPFE9osIUfEvBQpKwRjPutxUNiAGefP4kp1tQczcRZvTMjw9QGVQjQkoplrmIRFOObMWCl@A1@oMA0h54k0tPzpuVRajzd/wTy6mjCAJsYw4J7TOPji1cGrw1HonS0fVhrHVXR0hNBdMWukMSWfPfwbR3/4djgOwkTSyAsjVnBp6qTeiVAD0worvshYpTRuoFlG4caPBw21A13KxC36QeT4YqZK2jgn9LxdPCjGY8wNO5DG4Ej7WslA0vDhyTK1txEdWogw3XRJR@LL0oUqfj5Bf1oatgZjjg5gRnM0I8RADcmlIjFM1UWyVfhaxgkw7OwDN9UVnQ9TcZDKsrp5IfNvN//mezd/AOsiu/VEsLwpppTGZh5suJ4sF/aIueFa8wotaCx3hujyr7g9Ivc0WnGw3F5uaNMUrge7IEFnrcnvieMJfkkdiRYK1jXHu6@au7wseV3oITWaJvErPOVrQpDyvIFwBJGMYp4Um9nF4KbLGwc9i2UVO7MaOaNGzrgIQ89yGnkoxTCQp@224RCdtnXgPAJ8LdbopWuhCjtvMT4VuyJabpg64z2HqEBbGMKEIp31DjNrP7AabW1aKQRIiAsI@t6gMx1G64X0hteqmS@zR/FQ6j2Kv4QMeK8AAqMtuM1KZY4hMnmxQFG6T24v4ddBodiqNqst@l@T/1@s6kT9/9ZiYjMJ2UomNqup//1KEg9xZLOvRa3mKm7IhV8sqfE8OglGK4UlZc5sRWc2@iPkF9TXIb8PhyN/PPYiCnOkjr0RPm5j4Fc/QIkFOv/CuDrw@41H/kXWNXLFT7FHr8MjRHQkiOrjuSre2izCuJ@Og0mkvhz6Xf0bY5TfXdVf4TxEN1Kh5xEPFAITJM/cqO@7P5nvRLsjlEs00GNyFPDv7jDoNk7hKu9NyJVjCGseIPygPpmOGuRuyhv18VmczBA6b6BpJ1AddK1/BGBH2C2njJQXeuiesvhqNhgUyXmLN@y/8JBxQ@mRMpFUdvrEd3TCkyJua0vqGTBh6@xuRfswMV66aMQ9VZLHuNqQ4zmTxkDJivSFGu8Yy5I0M4qoFC3v9eT6r1inB2goVSwTW@aU6UQMohheq3JKAVYMSZTAPmKQPmaM8ayIe4QhQj20LJFGVJSSBGpH/CmVxglUkZzPfhXYQ@yVtqL1HJhW5hlb6@jeE2Vlbqtsdgof7aRaa@sYm4N6ggOK0yRPw601zCEHlaHCiHPsm8buR8WVlgAgTwgFQgQee4IeGbqvSYkUhXVweCD91XUeiie66BJtSDFeUH418o4pSoo66/ocCqbvhwSAJRvHX/pjGaJqglS702NgtWktUGQVPwyn3p1P1lapQRTXSIP2g14CdKUBmNG1bIMadxKdDk0v7kUnaui99Ybs/42bTbFfeFESnTmyfaK4@W6ZSAeGMtFTGAXnXpXTtrYfP3mwv71VVbXWHQRnA1UD61iDy9kVyicDDiEjLMLLt969u8pE7oTV0majVJamb9rDXrEbrBHAnjXBe9zYKblUTCRzjBiuTH3cq6om3qKJ7Ya62rjcsCnTCUYtKOrB1St/aamIJI11LSEJJjZHKFOODw34go1nASh3r4ARkN3tCC9hGEqIKLd4/2atZtbUOv2qwcZaq22wnXnxEdzD36jS3nSU2G1LtHY6qgSbHHrL463tZon2hXqxrU7c0kdhqY3cueGc3jrT8rkO8TcaYCscHrj94OFcz58z1VorMCDlg9ZhuSwJpb/7/3Dtu4jNAoZOVD5H/vpLV7uErfOmvs0eNJ0SS4Oh2Jf1yJtFj2hzjdyobQp0g/68TiFJ@4/g7O07X9p1jJ3yOWk391z3dvkcqpyM0Q5lDJuhtw8Yy21MGyTS4ivHq1cjdIu7jPev7z198hlM@R76lwqjgy8Ol281qqUSHPGkgeRipA@1tfv0OUoSJuU6SRQeT4JTGZdJx1RSx4d9tBym1leL2LUGrkLYOY@9SHofPpzvd46fdU7hxtyBIUgKcDq21g@GuUddfnuM3GJycovl82OXoE4m3qDNnNBF6L51jsvtCP6c2FXcgSrclRXCHkEhFx0IpEbdH8Fp/dn@0ydu6X5HIVY3Y1WUKl1DHEAoRDAOJtGFNkE6GE4XqSpiu00iGPhXKRU3kn253@hslNoXF7nteRJ0@uzxqxQTcN@ZVoXiJu7ilLYnMRXMx56LCXy0fWd7v1iFsnj3xUSKcTSnTYudEbu6DiY33CnoCJy/QBjXXf34Y0rDItPQdVeazTKqh1wANvIBAWh5YU3aF5OO23fMQHbGfp1E596M6yLmZKW@0uiMwjNgRxutu817t5ufBhN8N@h7Ye/jELYQt4MhZf1o/jEa8pM62XEwHHw88If4YHVzdXlt13/4r75378XdLafX/RfAQxZfhwE@4E/GdgMmnTPR/oM9dtJj6qJGjABnr9MYd94EjdV@s7fWXGt90vc@ueOtNW@v9e54t@9179271xusrnX79z7pfHKn122g22gqUj8l5cEikz9WO7hetXmM2dpK895g0Grd/aR/597g3krz9u3V7tqdfnN1dbDW6ty@fbe/sta9172ca4vbU4ANVu@7eHakd@CP8pm7wsLeLqXL/wg';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxx                              # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU  ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # =>+/< $f &&195e a 61  \=>axfnuen le./_e _=B[1;#]>847576097 @Numun Cr gu8IO nd eX"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t}a,
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!! (l(0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 41);(!)=seq;instance Num();f=(^);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

[Suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41388740#41388740) by SnoringFrog. I used [this interpreter](https://github.com/stasoid/spoon).

Invocation: `spoon /q /0n /1M polyglot` (`nM` are used instead of `01`).
`N` is not used because of Fission.

There are two `>` (`nMn`) before main code on lines 2 and 5.
Main code is on line 6:

```
MMMMMMM nnMnn nMn MMMMMMM nMM nnn nnMM nMn M nnMnMn nnn nnMnMn MMMMMMMM nnMnMn nnMnMMMM
+++++++   [    >  +++++++  <   -   ]    >  +    .    -     .   ++++++++    .     exit
```

MarioLANG works without `==` on line 6, removed.

Answer (score 6):

## 223. [REBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebol) 2, 10590 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM3@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WMqUbTntTKft9CWdmbI@JSVREm2KZJKULaXTH6prFrVTXf3QU9Pb6MvOVHXv9m4vMMA0FvvQg@nFAtOvg8b8hq@eFo0F6h/UnnOCpKiLnc6vqrGzwNAWGYw4cSLixIkTJ26HLcnq/@Y3QbzYka6Oe6puM1u2bNYxlWvZTLDNMXsmKVY2nQkEEKpq9oYDWbOtYiDIRMYUra104J3Z@pWsKZ9kE/zTjBmm3jOlAbP7ks1kqy0ZssX0oW0MbaZ3F0fLMFYb6JdKHGMOFK0HYLZsGqZsU/gaY2eaKg1aHWkmJDuToGFCuMW2ZfXz4LPN2vpgIGkdCyBzjL3STUtG@LZsWTpGX2dsVJPbM0jzACqZir5fPXg@E1Rg7DlkUTJUecSklmWbUttWdA1pkmInB2cnRzMxRJG9Od3ZmfVNs5dxXWM7w/bVbFCGnZmWpEqz@NdYdWjre/asf5ZVe7ImsXSikEjPBubYpinNRVlnpix1uooqJ6BCWJz1ZdWQTYY@rKubbA@ypOZT@VSzOomZaGPc/CRwFm2BqZmMPVOedAoIr5t9WYMcpmYDRS9wJiDtBXQUSkAyxyxs9XUT@MhkQ0vusBvd7ABzaeo4EoP4bPSJtSRLzq0hgoyH4ErTbzRgIluHqm2NbZlpuhanyAi4xsT95ixjpbPoWz3cm/XPsfT@rN86MFr7qjtfl@k8O9aN8axvgb1S9hexcybFG8KW3oHamAkT2ZEEXpTMNOEz6elW0IbahcbMLi3IWEdmlqYYhmzzQOAV2aRgiM1URbviDfzI1DvDNjY@uy9D2thgkR@sQBtiVZjhiIkEOliQOIiDQQ5O9IHsz6/FNBkqyDLkttJV2pyx5JEtaxZk2UowBQpxo6gq68gqRJhgb8eYpWP1TrxaqtRPtBMBZExMhQ2uVKawtmEwHgSlgCztpPJMRuqxTxCu9i02MgbMUgYQbLf1bleW2SfZ6EP0QEcPMLjaxkyxvLcVGWA02SWNbIBAQNLoSGmgk0uhG1MC0pqWQwNbGQBhFTtkMVmyFBSoEMWStQ5R1fBErc6kKZZn1wo0eCj60CTclmxSkyO80DxNGVBKXjWHb0zFtqnVsCo7kiWTnZqyHJkWu1NJQmI6pmBjQRJUqRsbodrhTggql8dISAZUppk5ff0iILFEma00S/ArC0IpUDvYZrcrF@jmUhYYwDDDUoSVv2NW8uJCht9IbCV75l0AsAaAKipL6oadlOIGZDBuQwaTEjrRFb9OJwzVlzDbmKkLH8txqA7UBggf9iZGJWsPTRN7kglRpSsotKprPaAnFNYcakgPjeVSUAVtHTqCGJOvgWogeamOQC4ghU/7ClSahVXia1i8PySCQo8IbOxQ1E3X0tUhwUFMy0ZeBqpAVMS412VvWFdSVIwC4YiK59qUraFqY5yh1sGah/5O7iSYmw1qsCbw8TUkJwFS8gDWH/jaJWUKgKEidCoqBn3/h3/e6fUAT7XdBtnmsOsb1tHb1HNLlFnoDhkyLAhUlbIFcDFMnUeHBK4lVemQgJC0sZMEZYJSvdGHaofpkKB5o0Ar7UvX0LKhcbVtmTM57@xjbCBdcWmicM6Fgg@kFlQsJUBpU7Hj7NkW1FJbDgSJZ@KDod3Ns7hRYyEr@W34aTH8dPlChsxFEpHVlWSyVwKGS6ySF7yFHuKcN9UpSWnZkqUrnYAxtvu6lmbxNhPaZd2QtXBoCkcoFjJboUgCpVw4UlLK7URX0Trh0AbwYgUSDkVK7XK7rhQbpZno/iQBzQ2iweYqh9sRIQAihxrFdXIA0jwBncObuOPyhelWE0mOwQmfNxJm1u@aewRJ2UG@1JFBQA4lLFWWjXAqIUZQTCDcwnJjwKKSzuBwClxUGtFQMBT1F50wQEmnCoqN9VTRUWypRh87LSCKZhnQE5jIu23oqVEyWooNGmeMtYivqRcByUIy8UYOmTJ26R4fUZPkTQ7jx1FQOhgmTWi6JcsdX0MGIQBt2bbmpLGq30CClCfsZkB0aJio1IOqgci8IFVeEJ4S@UwXiSsagK0ls3y8pUAjwOYGMt3heV/ZADyT5jCAjTcSn@wZSGPA0ubd6qTBMKULbWkA4gG0obaMMgeEj8w7FExkSO3PAh0bte1UPJ3NTrexuSZmm8lq/D0I6U/JB1sSFt7fmFDQsK58w1RJ6w2lnsw1MSa127JhO4IKSmLZIIpm@xvyjDudZ8LqB1aezaZNnYirWkzSQCHPa8/pCiWULo6iHwd1RmaSM1QBzdEEsaSOZ1MHgOuZxIUPCDKVgQ/CPVlwNQBgMnkkt4c2SDVg4Ju@0u4Dz2LuNC4XeSc0mzx4@VMHyR7vekljZsTKk3QgkfS8MBv3oohjjc7jgc4VUVWmPKjy/R4PY5aswQLEupdF6Ah8vomklADe@wLOga7pC5ACIT20CDIdwusBNLETVCih43LVLmqsnpbpVRHUGQ4EOsh/fds2rCL0E4rdH7YSwCnJU3O8Zx9qyCxJ2xwrts7dLVVvgVi2oH0m3RSS7WFLGc0UiPy8Ory0AteggHUtVoae@@MQuC4c6logMMl/C4F9QQIJbkLB7wIAElACCBXuWiSKd0ConIy1dlhIUFNKQKMTYkzAhivAcEfAWB5dtvQBSiF2TooBanow7FM0HCs4Mp9EvrSwq/NkP@l1oVDiUle08G1oeXk5VAxVQLIvLz8F1wa6nqIrCq6n5IqTC@ES6KIYMXJhaJ1ioF8jdFd3MY8iDay2EfZKnxQjLNWLxUwjJtVF55nGZwREHUg2gI7jA/CEIuUyOiMRoXIDBU20utOl30LpfNI2FcMhwgvpWuLvDhUyRAZlYOAw0pRL2Mk@TJNB2YReEJTWdj9shi7qqYvGxe1FJ3pxF4ph7EhJKregUJBeeJDomfoQustIfa0YFxuRSD0DnWSrHEqFVsPhfFyFhKRI5Jt8JCpxaodDMkjt8MVFCIjq0Kfe7puEbxRLRyIeqSAf2DGDThgOJW7zkH4r0ohEQxA3EorBEKMcCgFl2kgEiwqNnDlFoMPjl5wwW9FogNhQN6/wNyf2wS8BAywefQf4d@tketg7uALpytqWiqpI3OTaCLwmV7lnhx6exlVke6SxatDdQgmgt@14IyMcjWtD0p9JudX9CdFwECHID/selKvKFAwi7iojGCBAux@7ihD236gLbcGAU1flxDmpJgKDhoPDXjmxUBs64t1Kom1NeAD0HnAaqtSGhj2N7kJgF4AQ@DyZXBwSKc0hnlWVaFTzpTJCx9KWNKRfRyGtfahYfSQvaFY4lDC7QFVU2UE3kIlqe6wNfX4PKC2PFJvr8MBHJxhlV7LCEdQaq1zrQmUPNQbMlDsHQN253obxjgyaA4bywSOradeKqWtI5EQNUAPDl7AOZpAvIi@wUbW6l96@n76LkAPF5rxFH239WGeJ27baLKnpqt7T2SoAIGsmEpyx9zScKgGdz4bhJbOUT0Sgak/XxjM8KGN3b6GOKOYynvYtIWSS4BOXIGvY4kJPAO4p88ne@xr0EGI2lYL8u28purxC@rDMlhE922wC4EzZqsg3WJPvZaM/nppQQv7go0jgJ13mDZOP6yXoUCFXTgv/RFH9jZz7QDt3gzqua1HZa6Qh4VSGf5QxVXpQBqGdOsXhzQZKGJzxRl@XFFNI5yp8Ur8ouC6SU3LLGzjFuwPdlpJvEn2L4S2A@kJcYYKVDC2HkvE43gUKYukKS3bk6yRKKQczSOXT/lAOyO2@zoQL0F38QAKI0D4o4XEohGySmudFcyanA7Y@BH2xI6vKQLH3aCJN1VApmnT4bijOB04QHCmyHXBGMhPBjZNdEymu9Tj8MQhFwgpjhwQvuSl3kqs8tDbCjtAKyPRkB4fbteZR9XS3LCSHlplUlRa0nI7cHIDCq8qWwGYvTACScuJ/ulKPdd0ucza5UtkXryDGcaPvbzf39zaPq8fveCYIjaUMhqqEWSmuzABg9BMKdluzb/6xa@oDbyRgOdW0ksGKkafWGnBY7ISuYejQWWnw@efQf4CrB4l2oNdus7jOXz1PB3AdAXFFgfrOXjSKkLTC4Hk6kHlCiasMCbPlehbQ01tfmJp5n6BbFH5/JAfzrZi6Q@SWNrQMX8luRZH8r@1uF7UFzztN3ldxbGLqxDtD3nx9YnplwCHLXNBCYA/fGuHj6xoL8c0FLQT28GU5PlwPWYxuJmQRqIcsR8hw/WQhrpmABYAepnXC5F9zmYTlKey@BRcnrYXB90bycBcINy7KTFDREo3j5QKmOXcM@IKJ1cS52QmPpMWpUAziyyws3oFB0QaCIL98xgUY8ALt0TI6CXtkT1Bk/CjioOvw5RcvnDOCqDalJrTKSW5dH18Qi6sg3sTcJHLWi6zPRNWVibcHzus1rTZBBAx9Tdr18Qd5kXgVuus8/kaR5jVo6sbY15Zv05z4A8URJ77WleHkJjmEWpk5FcipbbhrPVNhvFny9Z3mJZ8kbDrLO1gvXBCeQpe/r4Oitq9YtOrql4wBb0BxERDcUdGU@i9MQtKT2UkWv148rSr4EZHMBrF6peNgfOJqphJiFrF4KAZX6nzMLui0dJsCncvUfAjvKwatLt0WABSdGTvoNHEJCqnyAlcdcFJRhxGGfENgNPfgdJOgCEvJY3rgLMSi/EzPp0xlpiV3h6B8J2FwiO4vgMULeYLstlrKfaBAF8y6@1xYyOMhDIDSibWE6I62cP4SRlx8MuR075AAof325ybh2FRV2EPThljO8z/9qANVMl9hfWlMQxDP0QRKErd0760/Jyq@0G1xXRPM5VBVJCIMub6Esi3huoekeo7FqFGnYfF4XzIHqOk71Q3sijdobw9wHs@5KavDjuw@FydSZETk6ck@pikD1l4ATbAz85I8MRrbqbrUITLwEZgiUyQTK5tXgzziYxGfqgvC6L6EFkwfssl6nd0f2kN@xyW6L1WjYuDvPiJMwaayUkuUk7oltRT5gWo3pathR48bVz0qNGYttwB2Uv4WznbFu6p0xZ1NdC4mAC@iqfR6suk@7wO76cOggkZDyRt6PMAZrmrFSFmWHsJpqvx@H4i7ScZz3E8nRaXbIyraYyhikTY0EiQtrsPHfWRSZgirSq0xjgr7X89ZmCDprCBnyu1oNJXBTtZbdJms@BvG/fGxZ6b4hcLi2HwHACfJojFLkq/8x/mMGJXZ2QvwhUYOXZcykNR4uuNz3ivF3dnWiWsBKE0RxNuqZAEz2U51yNdQfXR7iMGxN2ojW01cD7D3JDvu2tt9yzhOK3VacltXFQubs3qf1Jyd@Z6kiXsw6DaJim/zhO2QGmz1455rsSTQ2zauodzDaI@QbHz5AheIfJyT0O8jWlu/wd@9ykVfv5b5fXHn9mlhrh4ho@IqsYTSXihAO@0vcSquw9NtMR2vFubLbqsL/Z3VgumhwGN52VJU3YIxOd4fIgVo15bF74u52E81RdLiNKntdy@O5mTKYAlnEu@eupTUnq7m8r2kBLd7K3xodlHyO8/HSjxPYonilyWWqwfpmug87xX1V0nz6kucQDPfJq6Q@ZwP9LOLxJazsnJ/AWH8gMveiwu3k8pTzESST5DcVwFmu38jjd3nD@hN7qOu25sYY9KrQc3DCIU8OGyT69o/JLW1h1PrPE4kzaFd/1IhfJV7pcrQedF9rkpZOiV@ZQwxlXq8gOqqQ3koL5RPh61LGTc@PjDaeHymUk4xVpypxCQQDycSPahPzqjxUbnGfhvfHhQwkqpAI/@idrNQ3hmgixs40D4CxxE65iP2tKExVblTozXt@GHK9Q23ZeudqUxiyNdKpPyXdagpdd2S6Xefal8b6DA21gegNmiPqH8HKc168PsUYvKZKBpTkyMLk/eW0UGXBdUDalS5suI4a/44oZO@b0BPwIVCUlM02R7j/T5KLxKiLV1Xv6ZmQJZ2FNrgrMZxS@uXamhOzXF2VLDJ1IWF0yCt7n2TFryfcQaXQD0cN9sPjJT9U1EPjAbnptUf6K18k@xfGl9CT02zQpbZdt33MSRNfoiJfGL9QXbkWqjeklWJP0a5tYfwFRKZB/F5Woej3tKSDS7z8IWdyZpbcEb0GGMgltKBsUlfHsj0@oBSL3Uuh5b7uBdopONvQXAiSQsR98QzFGjrGt6nFpF82pCtazCasiWzJ@NwRMV1U8f3Pvnqrm8sJO7eQOrJ/PzDQ6JjMiuBW@34IG7iXDw/UeS7X9oQjW8OeJgVoOFcyWPLfS5E@GrchvocDr48qzbTxts4@/nFRp1ILlzW@YK6p/X1vtaX@yY1Du/tvuYBHGnzkysPFQLy35esK9xbSPJoMprrW37qqrqqPoa6KA@5dNT1xROzNTwX0IGoX4V3LLUgwHl8ccYOumwiEvXd97WdvjyEnsnSbd2Q4/R2H6iKkz38vniuee8wZLFzRTY7fGMEqOOQtNJSZXajQBYuLf@q9OKJpJaqS7h99QHlHSjjPh8zNdXWzS/Oe/Qk3TYMejQNdWjRjWZ043SKY1Fxdyinj2EGxeZ7UjjLyj291e4rX8pSS5ZsTblKunM4/PXBcakjjKnkCotvo3dCVYBW5jiBTFD2h5/gY@@@/s@3hLOw9FtD0xx/WTBM7wfwplr5CgE67kvfWZxdEExdPm66cjcXPbBM4azl3stNpECjshyXU6CViPfOAE3tL3OkFy0q3qP0zJSbMuNbR/uaqUtnMwBN4im@7Q7gv2jy4j5BuOvINxgVhneHPSvyZcbtd0CnwttChNUeHuXiK0mWqt/4Jpqh6Uua81jYK3urjg8tgWQfXANJJJ21zrg8vHd2S1UMi99ZvJteiGV@8X4earx4pOtUT0fu8mUKdH1JsxvoJm6yBxUi3jZlq40z3ih9uVTkIkfTeyCF4yqbALuwC4swv19gkW4y3cPF3x7IPQk33e0ruP9OteY7PcA8u3XgMYhfDyVLeT3UbXkhztktBI9B@UrqKe3dqVpwEbrUdXZo8cdUI0Cv@Yq46SsW7XV2HYsbDmczWo2fD5ydVPfO3D08EeLTi5wtpyy@x9ytqZ4Dp/UxXFqY1rTW6SzE3yvoFJsmTJ3nwnIu3m7x0CzCzXBgDC3nsTj1AZ5c8M8cD67I37pRQArGP4LQZX1JtRfPLvsmT0GfcnrCifM@Lfu9ouo99j6fYqB@gYBDpfsextqEfvlIsqEFaAuYldJ/5Lolzk3EuVJjfQRGkDMsrmiK/fA8jG1LMA5yn1ggrmrhyZzkPt4Tz74WQ/x0MVX2H5T40KWP2yqMbL4EdfTuCxDy1pe7li8su0BXqWtDO46nGR/qInIPdhFFNsrnfDzAwq9rr84iLiv0@m2@0/ELmpglw4huaKnjievexf4FHKbgKe77hex8DHdosC13paFqH@OK3mPiVQ1DxZkNkOnb@qIhzNEYupivGgdBLzEcbMttXAl8VB4O9FegnkG/ZYBUHRzLuHQ/I0juj4xR9/W2pALNOo9K7oTQLyrrqWTIm1Dn6leWl2PclmxpEVYZZ/@6Xxq/F3E1qCWbl/xE@4OQ8znYlUc0tLifZbhuE7fbba5G44zaVEvxDbIhL4b@halK0OVA9n/1KD@Bu2qnerN4@1FN4vCab@6QOye0s8NaROpjuaU/WHnOXl867@ydjLNizoZu8FNM51iulXDPvgdp8zudk3PPTbEgnt4boo5t62aCEVw4LEWjkUiAR8J1yp4GYC4UnT7Gk4n8YLPFQJTZBKt0Wb3OVm5HxVRRvGNlJhQF1mhwrHjRObnayKCjw8c8en1FapRXQvF4aCV0oRVZKuSByyr01gvBpSnYrkIPnt8JCZgm8SMO6HZLXOInL60@nWqGkWkHRrhnGk0842iZnx/kh1NPcSPU3/91xzns3ZOhsAMFNGYgCNo60AdyX795ytN1Ugc5JOFhccQBypXKjy7Gt6oMen0YCvMz3voNO9s5zTsnRx3DCvByxIdKXi545eJkLJ77sHnl8dx4e/idhL1YbqGgjxkONHajdOy@lYBWSUc6huZkjzS4EEyzTZyB6cTYHuvIuP@ETurQpKOq61d05A5z8vd/zc/L0nkd5xyFmzydk/eliMdyRDqk2m7rQ8i1i@STbOoOSBiJDKrWEKfzGfa@5B/BUyx0kBc4Mu4eY6Vk@FnWreoJi9dYCG1G4Om4ktINr1SPn7@ppxrl79ggKf@nHyUjtw7hhG/ihZwlxJgLUrpDxvIHZyF4EhpiwspI4Al6h5kUp@@44fUBJJI4k@F5JpfHdN1wWg2ZIqCT9x43OiZxwuimenbPsw7IigExrHxD51lpq7@GPQeaB9AsaGDwGiHUvNWVV8JDPuscP7FZFhLEM8ESuLjdAzreg2czMcrKiH1mfWQykFFiNgVvnJAqHgcelDfdHYkZ/77R5LbcGtJeqet0Ip0pU3FWmuWNCrlA/Ol4LL/@7cUonYpfjNZrjaTlEvXiYvRNKv0WqK6bEOtJElte7WD7diVRSX3@bEljJgh3oRLf5wpiYuX2aO@odnJaPT07gVq4c8XPjm4OpImsQS6iQyR9XSWDB0AXU5Gtr5A/3huAh8NsRWIbaMonEgn4zykQqENrIS6scKdPNE3F/kL0RfEt2Rc@D@DItK7CXI7ag24A6xCYDamGhR8aaLaBOXGdo@fEZQrKeGxAHmFwN/ECWUqkElgZiBUHYj2SVOz@wj7lfo@h2BexPEy2pwtBkGJeenUvnBdxIQnufiflNqCj/O3LzbE8XG6CeaDcAOr5unF2qnv7Z8e16WjAY/QkqVsuZJ0DOlw4Y0vjE9buWXs6Q@lExBn7ssAEisBfnc6M7DS1ZPtGhmI5wrE94JGJQyn/QmDCmECZMhq7apQ4LcJhygHqICUs1sz5oa4y8mXR7aN96G55ET0hsCN4qN2MJwQHc5AMDyXwcouBWB1yuU3viIS4I69Dll/9ibktDouGffTQ4m3unq7K63UsBv@@Xsl1pRtsxJzuTGywOEvDT5W1HhTYhY2UeB/FVjghhBWed8HLLxq9gTx1LiWaOKOtrM4RKeilVclACxsO9IFuy0X2cajTOVBXmHj6xQ1Oy0jcvhNVbVvC0tD5Us1Gaxluv0X49nZOyqidcdWM5Luf54YadlQA5LO2BGM@Ew1jdUnWc7stnOS6YyLE7SppJcVyTAJ4WoLFrhWLVlqwErqo46ggKbE0TsHR1BmdAGZV1QKdpAPdNzcMRspJgs5b8EMXcY0JQeDJhKcyxpgQQFirPG8yArrSGxiAtD/wyCsER5gtH87QxnI8DpTrKZprmquIC0I0U15ktjnEbUuV0FwUNwtFcsX79kD1AS4wnnMhJ7//wz/nBnMubHD/1HGPUpvw9jPnrQvuP3BDRBHe/qX3loa3n/O3b5NYZfNWQpzknXmCew@nAF8@E@bKhDLBtU9GZfFqG2v6zd4Rs2jVCutyII181YQSBnlO0YBeygCY4prqGMF5CpMqnOAJ198AiwBfAX@geoMaDaUnm40w2oooJpOYcZxaS9CJBnnEl6zIdMTHIZpMAiUsmcvm1sQkZDJ@7SKk89s93FPPEUYiRZCJgWvFKH9otfGoFBMsGNPL5VyJ80ZyRfo2I3zwMroCsAE@UKgziIOnq7wYEFZxooVXpKgYwajYkYXEEMq0js5ZDbTBMDkAJILemntMFdRN3SEV8LEmj2zSmMbuAKiFpvFwql3mhrNcRHFAxHGjYZ/Z5jjZJY@ninwNNOGvBuEcwU4QrCgsYtb6t@zCvtAajoEnBoz3ywWsq4H79xdYfeKchSfa580NhWeNBWFp2LMTTccx9w7kloXTyXQmKeYiPg4VHFSQX2zqnwElNG4QFm1ZudQNq7pV23txeHQyZzaHIEOzYCEWqmxEL@KJWL3hOUJevqeJurmTPHm1ueOS0p@ryYYjhJjsOprN5qLUZnN6T@rn/HjCfNoUMJeQmHosYlrij@/Qprx57JPQpA9wi@@Onks1HLm9qzc2KhdacC75z4tMiQUTq8hc4LqwyJBYaDabmMU999DFKZootRLu6bu0MDGU550Z5O8T7/sN33gGTyfWb9zjHQE6PT45YZ645@AHlD2R5EmR6ReeMTe/IGvcrIqY1UmC7cDcpjF/bphTlnnbrM4BSI9Ih3wOybWsaXFIi4Qzn2UiE1QezTy4UxcjNv2JPRrHEEsfcqcqrcCNYzPAPT7q2QtIWIaq2OFIQHMgZg@SzkNaD5p18cCkcn3EvBORFuqMowQtOYTJatpNI8Ct4jDXeE2U7N8cDYFuR7rBJrNo27LrOgadim0P@RS0zF4MBwDXpcexjL2FDFpWHCIDPUNuVupo8cWhRGLQyYZHkURfHnWUHvQ44UgMRNM3ojixnCOh6RfQq1qLSoDTUkZfgjJg1WQ20PDMKLJRoNdJAfl8IrtZ7K01AoAMo7YiRT5zETrTXCNnWPFFFop5lGlFYqEE4yMpx34ZbXyhiagE2@rjNmGa@uh2FVLZ/PYoeGfeVcxBAksF3Qxnoed4SMDPNV9lxMhHGakuJRStI4/CaC@i2EA6gX/o5vw6FBHmWJwsKTl2czqzJpVcWSjZjlCamCOakXeFgifnpkVDoYA2J/BsLQxKIMUT29wHJ6gI4e5AMlh4SDapLJZg9Bq@CGsxyzYjLF7B7vqGaSwapTkNeFAAjFkQtEsuhYx/hNGEYzhZhkpCX0vr4OOTYrC6mEg0wE2JRNgKzmdugTaFM4GRAIxRIUqR0IJ@AX9FzBE3uJtwDO@uULIBMgsDUAuDSU7h6hLIF6AFlZpVnvjMaUwEDKdqoVB0amNa2hcY8MXGAoEIaBdIcXeMAPR1DkcC1VBGA9SWKXcUkJfPXsqaJgOBgGcGaF9YGgKTmZGYa/o6NjFNSSkEeRZ3ndOWkNFpk5W10K2KizYryRJNjZXuQK35cIF6TdfRbMbJ/zaZSJZuwytqeZwEXTNSCa/0y2I0sxqNrmir4RUNta0nT3BG7W4FlLlmAgaoIwCKr6iREvAzKH/lFa20Im2EVzrl9CrFgFcYIt9ChO@sZOJ2RbpLrjwBZSkGPiYXOuEVi6xJpRIJ8Q7yhy1kJRkDnrlFs0hk0BqTX1GiUcxDYqWJGfgueXESpW7z4iRJk3clZyyQ7A2c5jajink1MWeImxPQ8S56HVYWOyxn52zTBZ4YrMwsCrtH/eMJv8TzBYy2RcmWf/AlTIc8XrA4chplriNkwtycFxBwFAYi4mtMikRAmPzmN0Exx5jwNJcJ69Gn2VQpGsqKMEyH8XXwGejhyVXBFG4vtuPXTO6mcx/jdamb@Ng4ujo6ehu5CLMCCwW3DgVxTfgWbY4/7lpn6Xsu9sOvYHA1GQgmV8Un68nkhw8fYMQBV72SqID44FekHg816uF1xirr66uxXH419izU9GUrEk6nIydMUZLsQjGsTgd@ep@sz4eD/Hr6lNKC4T/8M@7npO843BcEcXyDXwl3LWWD7GJdklaja@lnWimRTqX//m@X72K3R82Nv/@9QVJexschPn569wrdJ2L2m@XlbzY319ZiQEjuPnp/9K5ara5tx7JH9ezTtXhqeeM//p/Ly@n0Rjq53LAssRGqX70V0qk1IfH3fxk6OnrdtCwgRAGvDBPBifc8/ESWzbIr9gmuqy7Df3J/6vjcErpb3U9owgvGK2USNqFQNhM6@Ta0uNqWmVh5uv6f/@jwY9AOVtLJcxOedvBjMJcPcic44C3jvl0HK8ENBMvdBcfJcrkMzvX//O8gfuUF4MGQ8QbcKlkXV24crMTLFOVzsJIDh5hOQ7r/949@FAhWRsFPQVEUg2P6a6IbrvwT8QlDR1JYzwu6/gw/JYDXyHdNSpEUxfSFW5@@6saq9bz7gBvqlek@P6/ePa5iDjeQ47FwFbjV8PqH/@Mf/uQf/oj@/oR@/wHNrueWn33YZkyGHhivYvHZXD3sz7wfJ@JwJbzWEcTXuFOyYL4ca/JceSwc9Dlm6ODdmUMS7/0r4QJB13YwyqEGe6VN6uIiKObXDp9NVdDoCzadgt7FnGQ8knqJs1k/tzK8F@bKAvY1cIHgd@wVvzQN/uHnvqIPerxCP43fNA7hwnje3AfZ4Slcy/BH/3B5r3hfJh/Hm0Dmr@XfQvoGgvVgvdHY1fCv9RH/9j/h30cb/07b@Hf8Ef9OP@HfsY1/Rxb@vWrhn79mAsGNjY1gNHoMKqPDtI@5zuCXSDSdN495g4Hg7/RiAWgOjWj87q6e@HYULZWcf9CjSt4bXtwFOWrcxeMb31ai0TrlrF5xsrgRXzvMHbJnjQrPNd0TzW83AHt0o76xUda36JdoVvCKN76t1DemcRCaRuXZsyg22WeAotKo1wPBW6yVMt5WWX0w6jbIQE45Xhdz2UYcefBy1IUWZSFIWhCSq@j4jJIfuvJCIIhacIErwwXy@PCrH/0@/i5@9aOfFegjIxgSQB4PR59Gn6bU1HVKvBKvXumHk//DwxEEKKPUpW6m@qm@2AGxylLyWWqcGo9SA/1Q7IBThr/UAJxKqjtK9VJaShPF8WgK1f3/g0PdfnWoAzYdYtqjlI2IU1149g4PXwG@LqR9CX9KKpUaQSZHqWv4T6ko5Ml@IT2/bUYuAnUmfJBBhUiIoUQqlMiFQkojmzM@CrFQ86IeapSCSeviIsmVK5ZeK5Hdyru7ZrN2sN1sJpHdVqLPovFncJUr0Q3n8TRYKT29KMaxlt36DiY3nl5UMnF056JQgWn0i37lNcEIz8ryRQBGi@fn@Du/ub7hLnKg6@KcriYPPj9Pcq@bc@e6gSt5fQ@CKQcDPfWf6L9z@F/W/6szFq43IsDpt3cbYboi@BeJ3N7d3jn3SiQcdl7CG/CHHvCOUW7vKugkoFtw1cORRuTujvvBPRzZ4AgrmMZGhSJPAKExB3mqF6ESYzCuCjtLchcXo1QqUmqBjzc5L32m1Z1Iifa9rLRwRQ7GEuJqhECya6XSmuNez5dKecct5nKl0qoHlYIXxwlAsiW1S8jnpaARwTxw7g@ncEqGbAOHwh25ix@JeGoYMC4UC6nPnz2vZrOjmM0m@mc@f76AhhTCbS/lQhZ8UvnPn6H1hSIwZjzQnQXXAowAxWR6gr4vWZJtm@FPihG7COFOO@siFMHwdCqFwBifZTc2cmuVSm4N3Ll8JFISVviemXAvWhAjdytJgRcDRnOhoBMk5tcj5HsXwnAW3GBPK8DhFl7s9i5I1GZr2Ui4NZYjnodYKHAftpYL56MF56@8HGHJyipz/ur1THRtdX31WaMxUU1QSJRupbJ4V76VijjDcFdqO4Z5cSu09ORJpgBkyadKF4Fmc7t6Wm3iF05w9RpFLnqSuAngyqRhhuo0HZQtNOpYkMZFKFQsPeP1ms@yYKjkwMVDILhYvkDlDcKYU@niGYgRYEW8gWBRXE1nlpPZ0Te5WgrGSqt41ev1fDofXQWxtlooNBoN8t3gMdhq0GDieia4GjBos9F6inVwvdbEObRl8IS6Yy1cWrdkVXUNHt/optq5UTryciB4tF/dqp3G0hvQM6V3qlux9MnZZlDE1@zknYIz@H5cq24fnkGEo/1a9aT2fO9N7ewI/NE8KlyDI0keyk35Zji8wfemTNeWYkmXl5JhNA24Rt3vf/mT73/5333/Fz///i9@8v1f/Mmvf/EnP4HfX8Pv5/z5839byOL917/4l3/1/b/5C/D8D/D79/D721//4k9/xH/0/nfw@798fn/n/Hxw/BcAXD/79S/@6C9//Ys/@DP4/Wvn92fzvz/828W/P/nx/T@M90d/9TDMz/8d/P43jsuF/fm/4X74nIP/NxzuD/7s@z/@3/n/f3T@0PkX3//x3@HNefnJz7//8R99/@Pf@/7HP/3@x/88/f2f/i9iyn/7K2CZf/ybX@L/H/3NP/77X@L///o//ePf/A//@LP/mRx/zh3/z7/@t/z@q9/7ya9@/K9@9Xu/uOf@kwfvv3iE/y/@CXwen8/H4HlMub7W5xc/KD@/DTUmqQAPAG/9/vd/@i@Avf6Yv/338Ab/XtBPvRcvJErD0Hh04vlTxj4nQXlLPfvsgQLK/xF9wZt9nsZGvinX99e/@Fd/id5TsP/CjyElzsOuILCX2k@xfXgZ88P@FFvY97/80fd/@c@//@Wff//Ln6GsjK8VYtVYXPzCbBYAZh8Bh4C5x8ABoLiBC/vLbDmQBsfyBs6@BMTohw9A1mVwwVhhNZDNwFuw0aDhxkU9WblIXlT41YD3RLKCPonkRRLDE0kYajTZNzBMw9@zZ6vsm3icPyd@AbFCqCGPUehkRBjTrfLJlCiO0OE3CqwV4A2nV6LQN0Z5UBSCNqOsXC5HA6MyhBEovGKcEavkcbCPw8My4MVIPE6smQdtm402CQvELEePWXO1POIRo@hRIQwMM4Rex4KYFqL58jYkWB5tM8SFyKOBD/D8UK7ky6MKovuOsgA4opuQJECVMXejynfwXiacAB8YbX8HWcmXo9FKHnzKVFRKLdakNMUsFY7KHmVUbvSHQTw8nj5j7BtBzAt8/Ao1wxxovEcn0E9pGucphF9EV53i0L/rpN8qxodqHxF9uB8Pf4reFN8BALzxOO4pgx9UIwA8g@ARRxWlZOER5RiAclFnksXzIM0kGohS/UbpBdKHPDzu2qj4XhAdFmdlZQVcGxUhIxzCGIeZV0XLlkxcciHlrciEXEFAb9yiI68c0ShodXsV7iL815Zpmy0nx2pgJYTD4BBz04hHM/qaHqTcu0WjsqxSzqMEFwhO/LniTetmoDGvsUggTJ8tiGDp27JhwPOV1dvUR6AcxwQhJub4zHjEGWy/04vF8nfi2noAnvQ@xC8mOLb7oRrwK3oJbKxI0MptfIMaLjhBx8oFKhVn7Y@JgcpJ7RQinB4yMZ1KMNCob9fW02vZtWw6k8tl19PiWq6wlsvmMyD0cqlsOi0W1tYK@cL6HWXpGQiOWHG1ld2o/LO567/5Z4uuxb54BSpv2SjB4neByigeT6Ypx2Uxu14alyEf5BWo0CQEHzuMb@O45TNwQVvMbnE3E2QrcBtHNl2CiwWWAmwJvOACtLjqwZyl@L3DkrMmid@i4euSgpgFRogELoAROLaAsegKYOU9AYnzROTObG7iTKHzFI9AHkA6UBUa28c9oLbOTnW@13BTbgc2nMN7lUCAFnLqQNhGAD/4UG8ENpJe6GJMW33@mcYtUwcF/IfDbEraFQ/aVvixLS9oV0K7atZAsfv3QJwZAzyjI5v/ZBhqgxZkECdsOcAm3ExV1xcBrLOzo3tK@co7Uo0ronSmGsCP957vnvqep7Xq1m4gxzYPD7ZnHlkHKMv2azun3us6D3WjZj0U72r7@7OvzgMHUcssux6LgYyEGz5jdNEzsfKtCyIm7u@LgY@hi0pusJUuw5FyFlo@DOnKFWnUhaGgnEg2ZdYsb9aDjUp@LbueSxXW2bOD4WCIJGC9YX7vEIWdkFkXisJTQSyIT9lZcblk3tp3JfyEYVuypRjLgyjCTXIFkR/2UKzALgzPBvhBBzT3YQfwOFgHN0rgsLuFn2UbGuxeT3igFzpNpdcHEXijuwCBliQx@H3tBfFl/2U/7GHzNMhvLkRdAI7LgkqXpQIJmq1LF/LZfCGTzsfyBSCtmMtmY2I6Jq7n1wupmJgS82Iuny2IsfxaIbMGwhJCs4X1ANRZR@kmk9AXiIJAT0Vro1nlDbRPrSf6lUCQz3ZABxyWoKePsKAUbHq@wzwTMvmLFEQW8LMYlk17gVeVsoDf9k3hl3MBtcTaLLizs5Xa2RGETXzB2cmtlCB08CWbT6XWNwVBppAtkOxpQdB5HAgCMJu/pFKbW4Iw5AjwjLgg9PGllkOtVhAUfNmq7uxgOpf4ksb4AHbFQ/iL6r6sA5iGL5kMqcWC8NFDB3BVntAa5bSGL5gmhuzwkC0IE4Tnbn5SKcBwzOE4hl23rNWqIOzxl2oVQ15QwbM8qy/xpUqXIJjwAtwoCD1w9ExZ1gShBU7kSUFog6s9lsAPjVnjcWLNlgRhzAmEJBKEEUFL7SsB9C3HH5PZ3d2V@nZH7vFrbPJnG7IGIcpoWNtpPX/e6vVa5rhae36MIS9e7EqX46HZ6rWcaK0mXDrEgZCrwXj2gjzuNZuSujDkJYRoMyHNcVPGvDWlj5An5@phIoPmCwh5ASGjBRfHBtcAQFt4bQ7guSm1KMS9KISeo1ZLKCGj2mNDxvkhbDy0pSo2kNqmXsL3UXk5FA7FxvV0o0S@bBCO3KZKdxjYDdNHelBORm7H9VE51QAVXCzhNFV4eYBCKysUl6Wn4RG6cyDIxPSaECkur47CF7Fm5KmQBiW4iF870rshFoqLT4d5IQcSbxWeIPVQ@I3CqVCKMbjFIvX1xlNhHZEKT5/GhbqIrwAjxdcwBRSV6wUhUroDUtjQU7WGttxshsM3snQViWBuUaWgbJ@fn0du@Q6yMRVVKXXDo9iozHPDxpESlsWU7SF0VKk5lB08RT1s27rJEfeALqOnqSIVHvKSx2wkk5ENlE4oT@D54fzcNw3vTcf7XPxKsGKcf0VIzOciCdyZ3tS7TfpiB/vgA0QN8hzPj9DZUXejESnPVjFwimomfYOUoWmGFn62i47rwviF24ihj2zJoHQWAoGKo3fhKevEzlDDoiXwQ2J2yR/CDwe7XqfyyE7syrhDqO36bfGDm4naCD@/qeiaG3AyBk1ikNg7TJxpltSVS7fx8/gdnSLGI6B40FzpMKlcAZfUCVPaTIrcUDGalUq5WR7IA8Mew8iFlOeKFxc6TrbJOCQeJnH300MPC6VLlTQ0q0Id7sooOApUOniUfLO8eTssFgH2riSXZdPUTSEolLpPtfKQMngkm3j0Y@8QOnEZz1i0@x8uagi3BYS8vYtXTAalczOxZ3HieLv5KT@3mB8noFlO3ZV65Tr6f8bbRlwQGvF4/XMDVOpyqjQOSmVr2CJDHyzVAp0/VxqBn7i@VlKBNPy8zQrtupNKfdYqt74dlcyyMTTlEoF/VqFHbCaa0BLr6XQ6lk4VYmkR@j3oDyEYfuvwvgY/EX4QLq43lpfDalhgTIilRqmEGBNlMWbrNQ2ImioWkbZQKfQKTykSTa@q4Y7OpI041RE0wxJmAERBnxlKrB@GWMeypHLwSPTj01ycrWVZpPQRSGCuhDuJzcjTtVInvMmaEfCAzht@aZZbK/mrNBwpdcvhbyOl8HKkbMkf@diCSmgsAy35KGPFGg7qqeWcGLuNN@N3qmTZK@J6ulgfrtTjIhQu9bm3IbyvCA2g9F0ABiT@WXhQC0rg5zZRrkhMVIGJn1ECvU@VoV7EQrrkgAQMR14A@cL4kT2@CS0cCq2nQ6FIqARQy@BNYidyS8IhBKIr9EQEgQWddFEopCF8ImbmcsBHUjkxELwLdBTLYGuFQPA2cHd7t1GZKJwv2XgsRePu6xPGelEYVSdp3TDRDLJlcsUTFZxSqJarveNqyQGubtHoNzlZ62cX/JxjPLn8tQuV0Y3Kt/x5gevXkCJooC1drY8azmpqOhMIWrcBTj/aBpDciFaSFwFBwObnrDuF89kIH5R/FyRbt2zrtotSCQRK8RWSUyryVlVvRL47UNTbfCZeoZEasM3dXTAKhccNLpUkEbN9SPtKAkFNd5y4QmGD/AJpnc0KOHaXmXFS@Hb92/y3r84Ozw532LNUMV/Mc6Jc8OF0TAyJoQ32DHRG5bgWCBqf9az4nfaiFCwaocxaKDM1DrgoO@f@w8gm4Tqu08GvUYdBeSMCrnJZfCquFxXLWUYLF62hIZuRp2IuXUynxEjQ@tWPfobHktPrQccl5taDjaCzOre2HoEXWgVKi8FKMuisd61j1LgDJa5ng1bhczCdygeC@VcfPjPmfj1cSZMr6db@yu3kYrczV3LWA5jwDv4rd/WNjTuaxbhzHHi7u@PBU//0mFz3wEzCG982v20Wv4tv8P8NuC1vHTqlF3JZgUWCH0DOWFYwECyEYNAVYuksnnOMgmCFnqnOPM4TS3elBs0QyN/K8qpGf7K1in@T91XL2oB391XGQJatiAxGGsnkReQ1yNVCoZAT08HAb@av5OpSgK0uVVmI26LjvTJaovWOzYWmPgSI01CrS/Htk8Otl7VT7JZlDT/kzLYODxIYhN8anpx7bKuyZKpj52PDY4TC3vx064jpJjvbPqI453TilXxptslJZWWvU3S@uRW7ZmIig0ur2WRqLSlmmZgvptaL6RyTQM5ZaOHCca1gVEbF2tKNMR8ZhrciFHmpijAYtq/AyN2Si@z50T7FIFmyurRde3XIDg/23yVcX@5/urt3wk4Od07Pq8c1KMer2gkTqids70Rg53unu4dnp6x68I5B8HH14HSvdoIIkgGUkaixcoJ5wzS2YY2tJKqzFo3VprwtvX0l29P@kmlISTStPO2t4YeWZPw8ybT/UFNgIOgfBp5Ul7gWyBC91OmYATxqq7TZEg78llZBqcCTvv2Utc6yw7efUmZ2mbXXDkLrrJ060DIb60xNOX9MXRtkjtny8vKFJngdjL8Y3ijU74WHNMBvkqe997WlcG6NrcKIM70WmYQcHB4tpdy3pfPj0yXRCzveXkp7L3s7SxnvpQZva97bzvn2UtZ726y@XMpNoh1sLa17b9u1raW89wZMulSY4DzYXhJTAZdY16D3LdGnJsM7e/s1tgpAkdJUKM4BomPGGwgRBl2N2z1BkrPV1Zu@HqPBTGs8A92RvwTtgk9BLaG2WEe6NmJsVTfgBnooAEO0gDegkMxeO@ZgRTNk0C0FbgNLWKAlLBDAL@GJe4Rjy2WWjjAIXuryXR5hbpYyxoQzi87VfmOxDVT4K8AMMbJrRuerIYbsfHM2sHTnoAx3aZ60S5vGCVSEnAqmEIngocyDs/19nphBSm5YIEjGNd4FOHUDsEER4Y5FB19eObxaqC6QVkuO1oLfxQ3cTdVmYLY2kRRQzqWlNiCYpu61pMYYam0x3FmAePGFH/YAYAgGdwpc/DRqONzGsvZku00ZiiAxa4c7vIS4N6HMpms5wjBRohQF82Mknz8z9@3Cnn41p1@1EMftIOfZ4vh4TssIG0G/JfcYMEGQyQOKuYQcE41CbCgOhfnKtQREhx@3kODmsgIJpULsyRPKxwa8FUKUBMaLUoosjiCIwCEYkQ@ReVlbpuxGlpKruD2INguR6VzsR7il49bYs@4CknU2ozO16rVCrzqXNBgHl2YEshPU7WBdgzuTbsI7ikfg5BhrQTOJMTdQzGEgDhBjTI6xLnjPyNSmogHnyuZEJrqsAI2Rav9gm9cQN2VE/tyDSgxyr0gVBsLiCTZfYvSlpZYpS1clFwrkIUEB3yLThJEQHO7heMfbFG2VtxdkS4z9mJh7O0WXj3hsYAeH04isaH2C84pTXPKsTIDm8DvIsP2WAT1nSY4sGnUgPC5zwGrTcPE4h7tz@fILhajNlmL5q0uBYvneUtQeWYzfrhTQrU1YBEoBIj4MeKMATbfp2kwvQgF9IaGg0vwwFNCBTngJ2vgUgkfEhy53Ej/@9fGhky7ONmVot1CDXCrwKNOv7enXzvQrNl/wkdjGBkuvsc@shS4xBy60QsDy4OhwWTkdsTv9SvNHZSa7cbqeBOYpAM@hqORgyIDzwhglSMLCr7JIA/w2WJlVd5p7B7XT6VDEl7CaTsb7tq6plEZkGszJEIZbYXyJeDkKd5EIXN8MH/E0YkTP5snpca36Kgb5i7CNSQuY1QHg5rSEqRLcuSmArya3oT/uxFj4pMpWI@wJ5izGnMkIfHl0EqpuyYDq3hQ7QyNNSaU4iPc@3ZKC2CIDC5ISwiwcYZ8vLqBLTa0zcWB8zgwy2nqmw8aZdVR2OR5PB3GkvCtgDnjT5MoGQna4Cc7iwsQuUym2ZmaYLfdB4x6lzHn8VK477NuoW3TPShs6DcqsEsOj6ShbHMsy0C9OqzYPa5HUNyIfoC82Y/DD7pzmHKOknyN7UqirYPG8dOSvzcuXNNrpvMR5XjYo0fk8/MaZp4XhUmDmPDwZ6NEN25DwyLgTeEizu0foZQYCfJLGZ6ctrOP3mOxIkezroExpNtH2brMZtmS1C8yqD802dPmoLlsOGF4YmuCB1JDQMR3okAf1p@mAjoJHvNGyKfQ6MwjRggp4o1XIMKUYCHg5s2zZoFz5soHzcPihcn@CMMCeeodqxaOXvhxHio5WvCNhe3CR1adMa3EcQ6sfW@AN4nne12PTBWEe2ywIQwuKi6K4JgEWhF0OB4tyAILhnhDnUO@CEE0/XBSBW6aaBDTqPgLW/QRuNMKRxVUP7Wq6xn2mxYj@p@ZQduxk7R36WBCUS4cDfXUd3JaBadsKfuViFpFnVgBihkcRn4UDj60iE06SrLaizKJ3MTmI6IgufciBjYrtPmD9RkznIzEfQh/GDrf0ex9O5kMKOVyAJMhOiPfd6VPLQ40sOIt3Ej@BBjq0DgzvJhF04wF4DJ3AYuW7wEtoW80L8Zh5QZOboCvOMw7546Q@Vr84ZYXuPmi3EGLET9DfNvn41yYf96WPbfIHJV1m9el8NKK@9yJ4TMroNvAflJCb6@nUIl9VYj/XyPLVPeyL1oJ8yXArIdPJemgcCeTxlFsUQo8ejxQSiMuP6CvkC1WfY8NgUexJ/7NaZnHRi8Ml3qQ10Hy0L/MBtG/SbKJh4GaTLEI2mziz1GwKPAXqeLHD83e6TmPjYQnQUps6hYaFuCTEhHi8erK1txdXNCHGPxxQFixbN@UmGnYTYriEXRZIYDURpi@rRllwth5KFqPYwv1pVH1pQAG/nAgB8VT2NEpkYvH3y8m1/UXSH1EkfSaxiRXSR6R2TKmhwYWHUjK5OT83oS2yOIcm/ExZQUHDP4mA/KB3yTTLlEUQnNJ3ssDTtWimz0I7LDxL9Giin1PXaNBkX6FRNc32Ca6FImHOoJDT2nGqBxFMOJVzn3BEH05jZK2uIzt6Fk0PJYSJpVInYwmnpD5@dxU0buBl0qFNWy1y8htz5yYtnMacyepEsOgGFr4uoFEjqIAj3YC7Z9gI3J5pI3CjcSP0ckUduNGyEcboOg7HyBG4yMwRPIG9hYlV1YE0UgZDnLjxm85wNLlJtrDLx5JQr0@B09KPUxQhEiqapw47eCNRoShA0S0yqTRrVgnhF1lWijQC80KW7IBjNn2qwyKkC201RWK/g0ryKWIomi0nNxA3JjCBKyEUVyw2YPDp4x1XxKD6POOn81lPRAQliXnxJ/2VzzJTeWp4gRSBwQPPzCQCn2Xyf6CUlPtI0VNBJjXmh@KK24J8467hezPux@AqapHAAyOp/9@Mk/xV8l/oUOn/@0HR3NDnn3go88AQ5qtHK7/DYcF/Vej/q0L/AxT635k2f49KPotyvsXPqOtfVMO/Xv0imTeGbsPsXePUW/qH6GG/I0Vg/av0ADfXdfEhXeDL/bOLJu3v1n9gLx34TfK0kzvf0avV6ulANI@fV3vVfvUYjWBtpvaj55drm9s3m883O9Xt7d6L3taB/DpfXds3Xr7Nv3ve/fRRBu199/DF@0@q0e4H3h4bN@fy0U1GzlvV4fDj3u7Y3t08G2ydZN@t36Rqara7KX/cVq3tV6dvX54@z55Ebz6@OHrxaZAaWEfdlFQYZHZf5d5sjc@1QPZaOevs7CuHg5NO7Sw92N9W3u1Et1L7J4XXYmq/dvM@s3UTzaaSe8bLw@fHZ5et2nv1eG//XWfroy7lPl7dGHvJTqG7dXn8JnCYeS3ufjw87NXShee7yZvtrtFJpXdVM3v59vho8@zdbv@lVBvsZM8Kby/HR7n@69fX9kG0t3aeG76y1qJa9fXr9Evt@fV17TjQkvRTMyOf669F4@bmSC8M1uWXB7u9wWtT1JKH2TfRk8HpzXZtU/24PsqcvTt/fbN28m746vWL94cp5eSkVZNyRquTPrk8XQu0B5m96PVZ7SwvPe@cvx5c7@1m320nX/Xlg2rnSL163tt9r58c7e9VM9ZQE/e3rtV3z/uXr662t/ZU/ehK1apryax62nl3eBg4e6G0tuXdt9aL6mX/XTK7ebX2Ltoxnp9efupfvdg8OTvMp0dH45S@ZR23druj7eNcOp9sqx@PP3X1V@LZ62ju@vJFWnlX/WQHMp/G2cK@@k4eaC@i7d770Uc1GT0Txa33e5/evTvZvTZbVe3s45ud40vzVUc7tA5Txy9evmqpV3n70nivnZyI7dRz@epVNCUFRme7FtSRfCpl108H@6@N0bb@8XjvvZX7FL0@v8rI21fHb6ofj1OtG814q5n7ymAr1TmUqm90uzYcPW8Xrs@udtX9j4fWu8CrmpjN7uhda7P7Zq3wNvk82r16/nZTPBmlDrTj7lrOPHjz@lxRav23Z5@O29mdN0Z@YGu915/OBrVobX/U/yTnUy315N2VFjjLnhwfpW@0l8rA3tk9fpWzD1P7b446u2Ox@loWb7T1rXF2e2TmMufbb813V7uakXynfBwepeTraOedYa@9Vlrd9hulPXgZOHnRPzs4enOzl82ZzweasnmUTx3s724d9DprL8d7r4a1/dZl5/neW/mtcZq7Stc2z3Pbb08y9unVS7vQvh5kjvLRU3Vg986igRfD/nD96Nz8@Gb0fq06aMmZY/WdPl4XB1svjPToTbV2@Kl3dWToB@JOepw829ev1NSn05tPu1auOo7mR2f2QLdPxVFWfB3I3Hwy7BfGi9cnh5svDt@/kNYU5Vy6PHnTSWXO8kmlb2b2crnnYm2nO/g4KMjip@1XGSkz6Eet/atkZ6tz9ub8Sr0cvBxctgP5gtXe3Hs/lPRaKy2m3m12a1l5f3P/VJTPei9P1rYPUkdvO0dnH0enna23w7M3h0qqdvmisN9be3v8pvBy/f2pdSqd629fmgeBUT6jW2KukL3JnBTyh33zJHN@WbDfv7zMbarnLfHFXnog7yjm2/w4f2V86t/0bk7kVKv3fPujdNytgSQ9O0pJ2eHVwegkkHlzOrheNzaj767aL99qopo/V9aTpx8vC1f9/sub7fbaefXTRyn7/FIunOwkW@pO9nn0eOv10WVv@/xTfq2T2tx/I70d1fr2u8DrXWX7snB@dTgai693TsaDakpTs9cn59nrU33z5Hz3JN9/1TK7rd3LPsiGwfjs8mZ4vSuv90c3@Zf9yzdSav9tfkuz1o5SgRfy3qBzfPrybTXaTcsF@/rw3YFxnj8fZV/l9fOCfphXXla7z0evD7u11LqhnJ@Ozmr95OaWMsiDTDlSz8ytw9e7789fGKlAWsttftrSs@sfo9ejd7nz5FF0f/iufZoenJvm7lvF3Hl7ffT25Ul1L7rXGj8/upIO39WyJwdbW9aL6I6Sk8e7mRurupVRu3rAGmyODkamUci8v9rvQU@gdwqd56eZc82qVrs3e/mTWrX63GrtvZBGo@fddegj8Kqdv9HLgd9wA4cBbtuQPyRuIiUwsHotfQTykp9iDNBBtAAdRAvwo2e0BZvvXf5NcjVw6j93QZ/X5hM8wxYoa6yjo/KQYHueFWL8CEmMDXSIrqCrrRv0RLTO4ZIODvhUuNN8FZ6TpI@DyiND1RX8vhN@awLHpObkO36JwKHGBmMcb9rygJ8GUfATTY7RYPo8Bf8SFhktDSy128z9hGqCTOJ6H1T9AAqEofXiZAO5x@LxdleVehY41A65PgROPBv9mIKqSDj5gUmI@01JTGWdran02UPM3Cl@WergOcPPy@E2WHfEIYEyMSbLMThJRdZjZPzMoqVcy@qYvmYidxIBvuPzUbsg/X64N3zajwy3zuwNBXVDNmc2gBo8orvSmlx9htZ7nq0mnSVWVIaaktlSbPyId5MfymjyFN09b8b03kM6xOws0HLFCDUbMnnMnQNphG8zsZBitEd9cpoQ99NBiqCiursNV1cNQkn7rhh/8WFeNe7HrQx6vyvUU7g7ijyFVwdaDYFWtCA9t2b/jUWbHD2gUoAv1tfe7p02nU/e8C2GU0e47tlx6aNyyX0zSrwEvvw7OZ/flok7DCD7OO3ILYZDUa91zssC7XvE7ZFQ2zjCnuy2TADX0E4DxGbQbpT6WoPvIEzR1j2X4F6cJ5wTnvhy9WRC0CVnQ4XHA4@MxzdocpD58iLirinLBEC7Od2jJzOb/X7HvHdPzbRUSbtCV4lvlYXxgtn2VRZ9zMNXDpzK8sri7J/kp/eg3BDV2wY7yahgetVCAM6GWLeazzRszrTfHuPwGvaSxvkxTMMbdamq3g5PglfdLTe8bBE3JQ4/k9QhziR2cWetbo55Qjg9Ey6VAAT36ZBMkDV3t6qv1OUJNRAdberx5QL4tuR6ocUEeZLPGHs4tzypZWIH2gG0OKt8MxBC1b1sNXhS98tCoHfEX5ipqBPiuFuIwJlcZbZuABG6DsdBN0Y8wnenzlGF7/TyuIhxOtVTDfhnT/0vRb5xFxsUHs5nKEIi2IxxhD6TOS/TCFrxmg4mNWE9qijcwY1VqBAvMgVG@OjPlGh0qp58yOsK0k1kUaJ2eEEoiCGvRA7pHdoTDO2Jg9rgW3FZl@/g4rQOzJBoAxL6/NlrMPDqceORe1wUWIIfB9WZhQzOOZO3ZYegJffdbYSem0ImRPGk6t38Xno6JgsDcP3GUEayGgaB2cRP@RgMvJwtS4bBHQThbV8Cb6xsyrsjr5aXwxCrTnDJfIM9YWFxYyO8Hg@T1zf5SMRrjE70tC@6LzII6UqFhdOr4YwbeQ0jA8rMNIK1xQjSHMHaalh0EaQdBGIWMHAVg5B8w/Kca6cR532IPbyNaRj8INCC1FfTUbGxsZHHPZ4@z5nI6cVZX81E0xCZo16KTodwtDzA59@YLhEgz6R9/YgPxVo0Ayh40tHpgEmqMwFeov401xoLO6ffmfLintNwOx@Kjt8llc16HsuLnMo3pRsM3IZtOp74bTiDvhA38eMsvYpsDjoCNUlIrS/joakY/0Kg02kB/UozvaLvcARBoBggIrh4lBi7fKiva319Z4fAXZrg42WOMTHG8jAMAYkCEiMPkUGEEA2UXrM9MDw46IrzEb7jm3dglMgBrjjj@QGoJ1T73ZRIjHHy4Qo34HO@0EZ9CKdvGCI09/c28fGmdow7ZvcOnkMVLmE5Ymxyd4u5zDF6RdySNP7VGMVWIAsg2/iAxikrr6rp9NHTTd/B5iJ34Gex84hUOoRgPLKjHRJfKHZT0R1snJQuH8k20ZE@YuYB5CMlGGewG5lJKpJjzD@@nOffOqNDbxSbSAUOL6KTQaQQ0uz0uHpwsnN4/Iood9Ss7h/tVhEzDDDbktlh9DUebCCaJqu8U/XoGcDut4dfo8cySS330zEKGtYgWP5ZR048AGxSSJN8Z3OE5eVMPwfPvRdFIIniQYNS0ezIxgLcuHfVA3MKYy1AyGuR59rpCp08LeoJqcOb7wldOVpBSUe01GVLC9nA2PR1Iknj8iTp4tuEUSZ92pFaLupRPeIXk3/LLpOmD1wjH1lDA1eH5Y7gJ7/UbssW2WeYUB9QymqXEnEki49Q4LO49BP5wc@meH2vg4O@70mdbsrTeydq7rSyCNojp90P0nF9ChLH4upIt65aSWqRkzL/3vaU6qhMq4z3JcZTu@SpXUJqXOCyy1mFTGnUL6cUsUXkUVzyXHLd2NXMuHribSWnmutCo7f6aEGJ5kK41KEKw2oieyH6eErWPXGr7InbiictcbFy97BS5hB2WiNzOpxJ/@kMmDsdIFt4bm6DTq7Q6GtoYv3zF02@wRfqKflBJ3eIQfDEKU1Qp104V3ziGap7OQMxgTSk0zJ1J7kGdSoevrCDkMXd/ER8ugadwnRmBRQNpMXkcJpTVlIldcsZKPo8Uaw6vbDZcRs5QU46M7Mze6ALgdCXHzicnErgx/h4Qnl00rdBy4QaOWSis1IA11XjcYgQ4fMapNOAuMUyUPYUe3Ex8vPFcArn6mQKPwGDos5xi1wUIOhnGPeAr5t4aWG5feVwD8Nh5IivYKmSc4LCPdF7dsQyYibjO/57eH7AcrnJ6WA0zMbW0qnJkWM00cZyhcAPmiebzCdwfsSG41QoshXyDA7dQReUVRUaMX90FOz6MW98WDzij3HJU65W@QjWcsSx0zVYbDC0cIqSSThCx6OV4khMBJZAKNIcsPPZUrfzBsDeUDIlzZb5GUsU5M7KLiZIEVGHlU0oVwtaBm4bQ4k/QAN51tCU@QQw@HT0Nm2SRBwUD2p6OKDdSDFUGK5lE80AKLZz0H@JZI7DDlw0VDgTuJ6ucKi4vMFJ6IgEatE4ycLJSN0yUo9PvTiuNKkrp/spyuXpvkhdmvsFZMwAkddhFaIxdweWHALPdTM0Hl91PgPnNkkPeCL6F00NzncyfHDqjsMdNLyPmR/5K40FkzHEXW1/HzRyNjERKipTI@KegSMJ4B6BarvzEByIHqMGdU@Ei49GkYIwfukofC6ckYwgLYJ6KepSTOQ63KXjGOaj4CXvG/DEz2VofRFnZ8DYOTDnHY90IJDlIxzCORs5C4Htk0OM/DggF7yhriYn@w9GiMM774bimzjEHYWjO@KMCxABH9eS2sXzz8@kLS6F00YpUX4kbTanFBTxteXFYLzIDhiWzgcGmSJ5tOoZveFgZ0eTc28uIOWeJqQeyvxUao/NvJPcHNAUJR6ZdY8Qd85c3SKkEHmgX8t8kcrZVuOomb764UoSVKLDCMSz1O6dqQqHBq5U4Llr@WJwndmN40oSCnEO/c6LHAfKc6ym3ePArkD3pjkn53oXFZRzsltUt5hUg/QddlUxqGucLqvTLPxljYvzhV33FdY9ZTxVWCeSW855@w4aOLqqfsPtL2CHIjgnl4VvOjH2TQcXQxwffx/lUmOR/Js@6@xrkN@WJy3SK5@XVzo0673wtuqsHaJo9/M7xkO8KbeR44e4qQsQEVzXSu7meh5raclRZ0DpmYqXjjjTzh47uyi6XZDXtFUfTfHup11ME44hLGX2HcdDXdAn2ZwCdsE@k5zHDEQ82K4CJfXB@rjIkcxTjdTlDgyIRp3@rDw1Gzw5QH0vI/qxOLLTd0T5wfgkU@ZzMcYw3k0uxuFGcbr7Sfsv@TMyvjcjSA5aI3L6Om/NiJtEuPttV0YnupvhaG6gdxlpuH10FDFHf8umXD0gbEz0BW90wMcDft3AUbRdZRAntkCBh7ExPxodY5D6vfATCyMf@QIfHs2DmGQBxB@NTE34BRLPYdo3LDJ8g5j5bFLtEEUNXifT@aaKpIkQDzsvxhOjjsiS6TguA3JnVJwr1RQ6RoecaTauxI1/kCqLptRpnOq3/oEVv4qFxyXLyTjLwMPB7m4HQqEMDFXmJ3fE/Wb1cM8zbcX6tm0Uk0nZ0tHLSuhmL3mjXClJDhg4ccxWxeUhtnM0UsVDmrUz6MrQ4JSdYCcy36yAei@qZR9oOCkPIx8wElrA0gC42wWNV2vL@OkZ@wb3DzgIrIQ/sxAsWaCH6xob63prknvJOZnDMxCjvFuQ@R4QZthKQAaSbcm25LGcxIjJlgq3gYQGsZMwJE9iCZOHmrwPsU@gSciJS@laCmz7MkYnp2dSJRt2gTjOHVGIjR9up90jOIdg475I1tKhbrz9qc4ggexb6po6ZhqaAOgBpmuEBqkCSSHn3UAxacets6hDWx5kGkespQo5EvaW08NRPOy/EwkIy0YC/KPDRTzfYenILqZMe1Mp@tSelpk9GbxhTm@i4OP8ab82Guf68j4Nb4tHMumLq2uP2fexaI8H2f8Cst@38yOZxOlRQ5XGTLiRyBQ521pbT@WKONZSehqxIbYWNKLj09jlEVritnBjAPbjblxVvpZVlsFqfKNYQwA8sYdQpEDQMKXeQHIBw5kiw2R8NrpofD11on8SpOvqtE8Xz02wyYgaT6YxJk6w0Qkup1dBYjreTr8gR0Bqwe0pbnnWdYMVwdGRW8MedQZ4LsuNgaejpFgLI0iRSrgVeQrPIjwh62TiGtoxNv6yZ78K9xPpCqtDM28wd4FCKAWoFND0yzz3JTc@9hwI5lvRgQ6br2pAj7DKms5glM8SADT2YWEOZ/F5T1o8d0E6@t4hztpQgnxzsRuCRTQcS5H37ilZZb49JSAS0N4UMiaZwEom3ZmRUBU/wuy@bIZ4KM0ahbl7MkXEe71Vjxzu/oUu332yQTbBGBkJJXJGSu6uerHE7lxA3AOCGg7uLImH3J0DqGGauDYz2ZECpBfcUdhDaH0ZyHwBkioO2Qz7JV8x@AbvBp/tclSQ2WCx4a5hgX85VXKpwb/Z7tX/ZDHrCa/NJSr4Mn0B/pY56rTQ5gsxtEriLDBN5RU7L4dHiDs4LqeLD3N@II9pbnBmE2nSNOZNqPKM8jlXEBaoc8apS4mxEevh7DsfPsXY2HlF4/oBbkE7FRuXxZJnZlvWhoNbHIzEeJShEUPgOyaDtC8F8O6M6EyeuNe6oZcgsY6CPECCAr3qrj9ObdymYky8K1HKbfoQGxfxoEfM8/7CvVgXGuIr1mEoQv8N3k0Uv@kIMZ4eLhmQQ3Qd6UZskhonopfr0Vi/Co9iYxAdDM8jVZxRB7qdyXl6HfuCyEaJs07jCBich21KuO7YRNqFXQtkrDkqwwCpOS7jHB63/4UKL28WZEAG4YsMAONxBIQRKnOVXQonMoPoG0WjGA6DuunwoVHEUbYbfy4ca4/w8/h@/HcTI3lEh@Yo1hxH3H0pEKM5XiUSeNtT7uaKS9n7Lco7l9@Z8s7RwyvvPfTwyjtPzx9UXm/G@C0VBLoYeuAYB4fsT2FEDdCeJ5@neMrQMzXpobbfzcYeGvjtpJnY9NGL@di6YegWGlxfnAOe5oJMULjPH9J8ytMoghsGyEk@fSTmU9D08PMFVoA3cVNHfTFMbvxyJu@/QJ9U@dy200eTB2Iu0Iy@9xqfeYcEIk5X4vdyRaJXPkyKy1SuToDadkX7i8vMl1TJyzgVlI/BGEX2Sh9h/NWHw1d02r4IuXGjIKEibFGUIeodGG82CvotjuJQ3ZGP07GQ6mxhLLcSMbazu9LVhEjsCHt8lDTRugXfWlOTpDOwq0@f8Max3nzvKOoyOK8MmukNRd1eGoZie12abdviG7HZkTM7hceeQIW3@6Y@7PUZGopCHRBh@Zbyro7aPWqXoNXj51KHaKum6G6LC0@K780fJ9mZwWCQT@fnseW@OmJbqPi3xjiXzOcCwr5uwtlhtbTk6k5LkyntJZL0HnCDT/TxGYdJ8lRnvgxsIz9AFl7hTBwkf0zstCBhtxOLi54GIki2jeb@UbNWeBGw@JNoBi7DTCKiBuDa@CJlZckDXZxZzsa@3FLu/NndB1ZZlNvUwkzSMdTZTLZknOpLPZA5Pos4O3cD2cHUMTfb8j9B/Xmp/r/tfVtzHMmV3jP7VxQbM9PVQF/By4BoFgYkAWpgkwQNghopQAzUl2qgyEZXq6ua6B4QCq/vDjscsV5Z65X3ErZXa8fuq@3Y9UbYD34f/Yf9BfsP5POdk5mVVV0NgNRoFLsxVGjQlXny5O1k5jmZ5yKv1yT3X0GaVKmmygrD@STkQjmamB2Y5p3CfTk8awilkgROKJ@FY8iGs0ou5jPcx/Hqap@R7MWiMuBWaqo5JyTPvoWiUW5pfnE7adNUsekAEFELmLWStzO8lyFOHUo/ZXHUFBYBOGJWDn5npRlhF6/MuvD8SIzDru/3IrCsbdAKt9OFeYNarvqVsBe0jyEhkqSut17dHL6PZmnxJOiKVcaj52jK2P/xJBiLsI3W1GguWe@HSOHRid99w7CIx5RgrwbDKg3bMK6GfSf68aQ9xpVDOHZWSlFB7fFy0uwpTZwsH6U2qFYKmCnPm2dCLGCwn3AFmSErfV@Hqxq957GyDoKElCIVokPdGWFs7bsf3JrUHNqvzIUMHc8DZaEbRIzHEr8rTn8ywF4cjmrIw06Y7qz9Bcayc9MTJ4apblofKSDZWNO5FkalhjI2GFw@xtVJLDvN1eD35qBR1QLgqkAbGcsaXzNoNJSpcUs977BRUHJ/Qdl8f@6C3iIN04euxdhXIgTKNMoVrmQeLR/F81iH4bBqYxawecQEB7DydefP@5bmzwEDNMTeQxsMzN9xw9ht47KSm66kT1rp3EsQsuoK7QOnk0HcHvrhJBrMftOEULjB4UcV70xJM/78ofpMs@MQw0Q6qyMYgLNT32V1N@gmQFCnzXv1yTpyivtqq8HEnYbqnHUGygwmquhQQngmcveR90Tl4XDUOgGZHLhMwE0P1ARitvGqiNoAbZ1sLjaMa1xOK9i1u/GEN9GTEMoV0Cmd4D4IOh5jmIjxlGDDRl@APBz5Y6mMqG0WThx9PhO9Jq4@aYNMfG0GVKk6@hg/9mZ0C3QvBwnhAW4LFVQOj32rDG2/1HAC57sjarc@3jq@uqPA4SavWwguihq4WvoL3IHYwCUVfnBt8gqHO19UCdyZcg24FaDFZt2SiZ69e1PJ92Ut6Gf0n5hl1nddGlYISun24yWBtSrmr@W0ABu0WNHCDTxoatyHhQWtSwI9CA5venhrEa0NvjvDLJ4RgfjtcfeEukTzFYBg4jGPUy/o8bCRDIdrb@PKPHIIPYIllYWBHk5OO3BJ0@fxMmaa/O6BS3ICcRPUZa45Mb0MeIcLVoieX0HVk@@Pe2WztqQqlksg/BCguUfCCaraxPeXamDwnWg2mdHpu@oTVyGrGBZ8H6hEuClR/ujnslYPted6I/KttrIYm5dgLCeXZxmTMFx4xZaK01k4fiMvR7h2450/bgd87423QFFYRiF9o4dH/ijJk5cMfTmXhDXh9YyD5aQdX33Jq6kppk1xIAY9YjiVDLC84bUSpWWjjdwQ2qItrCs3UHWVBc0oKSsvl7KxG@LRb65yhyi2QQ3bdEuNtWcvBZlrdZUpdm3jQV9xVynaUJCKIgCtW47rd3UlqeuoMhqGksaLjMONX/E0WEuZO1XtlAuI/9JOPXyKVvzhRkOvRqEPzxPqSOowSsJdS1V3WZs3iD5Zavg5ELBnAjh82LjxjiHXqS1nqvS72NJqKhpeNzLytyM9PgBLeuPG7H1Gh8fCqIknd/JFpma1DFjuMMqAq0IbGSlPb4x9Wfo5pipKyVPCHdDx7iCYgjLfoE/7MjyKy@a5Xi3QKK5FMdOOddJXZfch@s5bd@1BFCpXZnywSqGI3wvf7yVGr0CpXq27zqSPpuCln8okBirz1ik3@2bLYdVcefCXkWJw1jucAIes/7KlLagd6ovVCkGxyYp64VcFD/SdONArNeq@uiOTHjjLR6pa1Qftwgid4Advy50NS1XfG/vH9GcvQIt6UQn8knn5rhW25DLx@e7Os/3tvaO97e9v773Y5pKsyG8MiiejOt@URWdw7j1UeEtRyiFO4YtxQOc4ThyOswQJ/EU3jGPnMYm7Ponjb9pUsj3xCwvf3FefLM57GfnjdSm/L8w8G9@zpnEUwERoAlUl6t@ZCODyPOxGZSF@OgPZIRW0XgfwZCBxoQrYM2kzlxzsn1hJnZADIDKEsmzAkRL24zNwgEqaSL8x00kz6NFq9mtKx1ZD48oh8ZdgHCKAAaB8aN3Oahx03V6rNPA@8ZxgI9FWCZdMsvejhvNcqt3iap0t6Rd4yPYgHB4XlPcEqwXMudGhVUFI93U9xGwURFVAbwGeAjHS0iPpUB3yQb1Za9S/OZcGySP2b8lbwQeY5H@gnfe8nX5u/KQ8s30dA8DicS4yNnSpsEm5FnT50ZrSBnWZilZVRR9mTr7Ymlyhv/VbtiBfYECuWnf72zEa/2btua9tZv1r@1j49s1wcgk4ZZWjyTdXxfTimzPY@btiNfJ@5iJXWVF8ZzqRbzqhAqq9j/FEabnE2sfgPHZ25cIeV03m@ifS2t0qnFGGJ9O7VkrR1kSwSSvNJ/FolCby9ZToUxr0KbXy35g6/OK@5tgCJN3NVzt@j15bxhGpjjbeSxPeBOq5QsXd1ta/SLVf12ur7UOlfTwD75lcpGHNqeamVaR5t3n3zkmpgYuli@j4MvkrDXNj3qKdyluXcVoZXZ0d@s5MSmbU3@VSMKe0CfIWqxhZEl4rHWJOUattk6jgGq2UQrySo8oa18X8@GXU1pMRTC5L2YmYfYmv2uouY2wQiIrPBtgelLNzlEKZXMYuQpmeGj0XiypTC23OJsS8wP99sbYyJCgGHt8ZWf0Wjay@sxr5zmrkO6uRy6xGlm7WJ9G43gmGdWLNBk71jLj/whItqK1d54vPH@w7@59vO49fPvqHzg93XzpfPHhGKbvO85cPn@w8cuj/289ebDtcwPz7vj@Gyr1DU7/ld32@nV9tNG47jHkuQPlt50X71Pk87PpviXjuR@3TzRP5qA39eENKbb/1x7NQnoNGUGaJldUE3xXJW5O@cYLFdYco@RTviNqXJ9rI3jwjuVli2wsOh24MuOVtj3kQ1uPiZyVjtEHwIaUSmrY8ybLuNJ7WmWnp1Rw1cObfe48gMYVPXzgPnm0h0ufWzv7O7rMXzuPdPfp8/kO42XG2duA25uFLZDHg092tncc7jx5wgjSgUXNwt8YG65c1oQZwHpXum/4E4cEGkArVV8qr91KhMAy1VUTklCbDxH1Pj0gK7@7i7LTFLtrdjx7sfe/74Gr8HzvFIoJcWg7VlQXCRw0YjVBtKop2S5ypg7WsNmVDOp05HyG7VeA7IP5dcTTyMr8TB75TfIRrRDxIc9xsYdg0aqroJuEGKu0I1nM4AkOpVLnPKDeoNr490LXhYrWvP1B0UzlmhRy5pL20RowUwRl3hl0Jo6sTiO5Fq5urjccCgAshlSAAuINBQtx@4@/gksS5oyAmMQR/SrgrCa9PR4/PwDXCwFUlPJRAIGuqTTJvPKUIcNQOhjKPKbMm2R04RgoXiRgeTnIGA33lyipxxP@rNza8yhJkkXbBPq1sLVQkz25EDbS3n7T7ceS4Xhm3wSSC@MNANLWOB20S9/heeAyDpbdQI@Bq1zz829CO6jXDyYE4tQjTmTnpdphyW@rg969bjko@nKsRenvcaShMqfhPVzbg4VwDPgQNIara@wXcCo1iZmwZTdhXpOxGIVEkiXzOT9JRjcLepOunCihZx30dfPVVWQ1yJSliqfhw64yGHUI94CHkDD6o2M0FCTGsKXmC1yiZQzfdg@Rt@BTKEGM08Ed6cFVttvCga1SaOKpS8PMLau202RjuylqZ4kU32GxfI@Mzip@/IzHL42eSDsRkI81F8OcMJQZ4dhrDzUvfgWLRLOaWSHCHQrJ3/MSJ6gdfrnkbWw9fVX/yo8phvX4s20K7J48XopQozywsktPyMLqTrA2oV5pCWogmHZTW@oyyW2KVa2TEuJwExHxvHrVMnlyrzqcPOV5WOp0T373zpFSV7U2YhBBJJtndKs6BrrLCZQ6dskKQ7J3UWHjW1SkVxmn2603EtccstGhEhthHWL3GDqvG@jWWt2s86NHOUlB8mky3wV/WscgVRfE/156P@pfuQ29lo1zXULyYzHC6eouuaMzNsurVBaaXz6s5dFuXo6P9@/ro1i5tnRwP74Vt61Js79W26spiXHIsWbiuj/Ynl6CVw@2D0FLfK4sRyyE5j81QuiHOykdLmuavqPFHc3PHa4/Q4OxFRFWD1KptMhzAQ5wrl@LUNC5QttEkDNGL/a3tvT2nuI1btnUqS/tee9hl@1Jsg8B9U3s6Ejtk3uxqhmkyYYIM86RTLsS8NF3tZYs5d/AWbBWKB6mo8TCbhYnaS5LJVFlHyMnCLAQMr2VD1COXbt253oOiA4X44gCaUE4yaVYHC7ndXJLDR5zs8yaTjFtFeOPoTTAyzIw/Vc66@Kp6PLMRaUYYx0H7GC/f@fP3hfDH67oeYbD8H0@4w1DC78JfvvOCKh7hpbiWnsFLpkVPKeusMJUu6bFjs7w0h/3rE5SJxX6heGFrW1fMsWqa8McfWZHsmD/dxDv/TGV2T9V9p97iOeW@PaHl5NBz00cQMZkkBjubNlVQ8cMLdYTxaJhz0jMMub3WPuLWHOhWcjQzhbu1GOhj4uDv3M1uD9mqaLe9tKrqN1OVnBKpmqy4W/M16EzCfPfOnVtX4c72Qhev/rq45QzJ7p/x6eht20IZzSJWFSLK3XlW0fkJAVwydB5JgT1XL5hMQWJ1cs6UVN/5MLLbR205G8MWjxqz@3K/gvuibK1lZ5ppWz52OZFs7Awy1wdrCZuOyqqZG/2Ly6t7yEHdrqjv5vvXJ4sNQLgPv/iVhMncC0fYKokRHx@JV1QSydcjaMXFKCHBB42nXysG5qaOY3kg8eY25YUbNtJS42YcvoFev46cqWKbFfEMVTttj87f4YLrHV@ZSh5sAlTZoOJsvhYdFYmsudkLWYmgb0JZbkor02m0zb89soNvrkN9kPMEwHrA9MwAlj4pOST3rONWQYeaLK1IGvEnJqkqSUSrMWQPk74s6bBLCEaDmUmvS3rPR@A5k3pfYTlrm4iXpQ0FmY2QWSoqYL6rDfqzIx52k/2ZZBMbY5I@Vo0h2XIQmtSbkgqdKp10oMpOkqRDSSJJyiQtKSgcTEFs01Lk@2@OeJJVtDlCWKo4w2BwWFP6U5@5SnYsKxOOWCaSyvvDXoEnhWOeGlT6SNiEa1lFQgebwWGNFSjVBgSZLJlYWUibQVLABqZ0K/SlEJUU4wbgv6oRqqk28aLmg83XoPCxH3UnvrM9hYyvYyNqqmTHIEvO9rMtZ/exs7f7fDuNGi0@Ao/CpbTCHodiVg3j7uglW6EJDyfxyZEk6s9s7pkvuRqFfBugYTi2gOQzm6srYBSHWJbO@bveO@eADu@RmRS3Vz5Uk657bPpQ64aTYXz@bvqOp3dKnF6NSOAz56KGS4LP5oZFrUTFYWty4Lc4hIUEX3mk3SoktXAK1zJVvjlCZXGdWfPlC4WtYPZPmjpambxJJwE5aZvEThCC5VlX8S1pOLonScBNfsv2HNfNNgyHUq02l7zifGoCN/p2xN10ZdesZGVRJfeSSoTCDJ5ahDiiSW1lpxc674J3urLkUMHRv5aVdsxow3ezmkbriOFll4JpHFrZ8iph9blXSP@aW3BqBp10vFH1uiELAkHek93cExpPgTF9z4GZzUGDyQKag@NVkAKUZTIHyOXnMR7ltzJZejlF8lucrMf55iyoJUGXUyS/lqTR6alI1npmNrohcWcSkAQ/jkgQtM7X3JkjspmreNFidbIFFSmyOHMkdbryp5xTh96mBYLo8VD/bB6K6Y1TsotdCp8eEbsFqvPWgGAPYncqONbs9GY23T6SnA2reBbCalQGmHBmTqqr50I8iaSSzmCpJcuKjbZUNHDwWupopC3n0AJlEloAWk2DyqpJYAkUIMzF4WSxQGUlpkFX8kEt4md4G2umrdZqNKAr@aDW@pjDWs3DmgZdyYLO7Wu8UabH3jC0y@7lk1dewMfa6Kyq/KnfncRy0minFbSGYloeNqOloHvBcRB/5iSMFv@qUXtAtLfXlEdsnUYC/p1PDevDBTSrbTdBVZsgxG5h8VJBTsVyHWWzbwljbpjHFLyEuMb7uAV6wBD2NDjigUk1RDMZSqDRp5hmxeyhkVLT2GmxMZJTdJbO6fMC3O/B0rmIOxL5vVgpli@K0qxWahelPulkJR/dv6/HohaHR4GT@6@lGs84wpGTxlFLki75l8IxiU0qrjgqg7Arl50V4GppYe2A0iGA88NOBgdeU@b7ogsSmsOr24EHlXkcaMKKc1mnbBxaqJrHsXxtHFpgm8dRvX47WJ7K68vH18YhgmAejvq1cYAC58e0uHROCC7kv8U8UkuNB8yiVGq70kmThsHZTn11sn3RoqoDe0HGkIKfZr7y2qEYc5vWB5YYdK3xgNAxPx5uICtpg45i3rkbcsHcRMny3HoR4ZZT5QbWWnkt56Mo7tFBUOsPzPrOWfwZET1zSaIQ8r0HhJha92RMIhJms6akD82AME5q/9ERVLOOjvhm6Pne7vf2Hjw9evbgKYSoJdmjcH0DbRlW12nUVhHPXm5bjlinyHOgaoFuFHgftvK4fQrNNp8iHDkWpZbOLbiLojBQqMnj@6La0D9zHlMWB62fwwnImrmboelxuQ1mUy9W3xbLCaR9guleKXltg1rCMEInqiUMYyUXLGFLyr8aiobKq@GrWAA7zoHYZEaHdntfwXDJKug41bev4u/74w50SarGaanMIlTwIbuxcyqoXKgb9ASDNYG/qtedh9oprrJfaw@6cHk76bPj29Ng0D7t9Nq10cmo0I885Z7GLfUjOLksQJlqZ39778XRc8Tp2n7ElhP41@K8/Z2n27sv95HzgrJuqeTtvb3dvSNWUN97@XwfHkMzSUUbUGFJwFRCCujZ7ucPnlgw8l1UjRSDkIjkTfqjXPlUnGB0NOX/ztjMoyKqEEcchIfNVFCU0ypOHJz64UQHb4P/CX3AV2B5gkcZqktHNWaHNC6uP1Ve4uv0woLidowno5hBWQPezYxEOV1CYE6jYxRgX0QR8e2sTV@TG2XkwZAvHLmZsjCQQbGCsu/qR7w6sExezIZdV6NTjjwr5/6QIPHaVJrE/epa6aIMr5IjVhrKFi7V6eSos3PUUn5JNYJKK71gBTGyr11bBW3wTlBsUcKTkFimcAF5QWw5KytB@bxgB4hSWbSrSvyoc8eyoU/DqPg1N6w5EremoudL9YNAzC9lgWNoRD6f249STGDqfYqNOQ5geW7GjP/qzsoNs2tmx@X3qcSuuwbtkUfU4AexK45e2GdfQnfquUs14AgZ2RlP5xF69TamOswVCo1HcYsGKh7PHLEgjGIzXNTzQ/x3qly7dqFA4xLBlW3YYlFyxR0ljISiWABYzCtuFNcTNzZilmAUhwXivg3RzIP40oZYzYN4a0PcyoP4@qcCEvTdlRU9eRvO6p07os2cms@c4v/DFK9WNex9rQqdFCZ8dnF9GguSbcGhoFc8mIPaZzYht1t299KWpVF//T8Jt41LlapyJdLwS5p9CeZf/pPiutzQXWOU/qP00NqgwJyoJy8xYcZ94SNF4rpJypY0i@0vL8FWLOpZzC/7BwlFfLmAaL7@qxRMPtn8TM@7Y8ZPv3DdSMo2E6uGLIL/NY/Aex8ER1Jery/2NioGvMheXTdYdA8SBAJyywZZzYLkVfnu0iobNr5mbpVNG6RxnSq//mtVpzq/ciD@2EDwXqsGMxf0/6QWGqvmU6E80EggYVPzPHn1XQh@nG6DXSwP/HmCnYscXt7uX/5Ott1JyVz4f5pLnFzApi897bkD/1@vi@PWQhw/EhTV6sJxKwnEyspCiK9/kbRDhje7zC5bJL/851eXbiwu/Y@T0skxv6EPbuEaNLLsFmjUg9KZXPTAYJP5owEwKTmtsY5Rs@asJYezWBmMpTvQNNnK4iydvaqzZ7nZt0x2BvmFMFiaS4J/PWaM7kuEQWaNkt9s5SsMl87c8GyurSwdsrldYdaVgTmNjeFxlCmOxfRsZASO5ZSQMY9a5ZYVs3dRYC64lSv8RO1x@2TYRoDWKBzWVASQIKxvn4avAxxU4zrcXNReR4ukoV@HtWYELMd5EF8fQKGCmqqciojut8jtAGx3u5PTyQBvaJ6Sq@AYqV6HyzgWBIeT00jhxIn7cBIMqAceOLWERSQxb0St5FOYWOlrVZ@pOq/a@SrrddEbr7EbOk7itnXHwSjmyrx5WQAun5hBpSqC@xasZuFhoH7OiMQVraf68yQY@q4FjyiuQcVKYL8IK56UajFlZMfEwlGBBsizyWkKw7macdaN8SSnFsHix21UVjFyPujGGfuIEGKsI4LIWVU@6Ni1DJAoC6JxGstq5XZZRokRPSfyPE1D3K6sNlDRCFnsoog9QxvN8naf3RaxUSvjYGwGmmeBOMIEvRrXjQb1jjJMu7zi3/7JT/9zsXxer@s0jqkTDNskM3BEkgQrPvfD5/rbQg/5RNkqZnD/lwS3oO753eC0jQg1sYWaiGsBZppAYD4nQoPTqnBA@0147Fq@YHSFIKx6/cHWlrP/@d7uF7CGkksEpoJMcRDBulNckWHnkql8pRgMEEUJ8zBPVcUA0o2YhzK9ApjpMbvX6buWBhaN1u/@Sx4tvssPoeku6zKDENlFceqDe0Lo1tpozURoCsY8/O6/EMzhSLRn8xGHo6IiTPo58on49VWkO9cvgciv72/@8N9wdcqihHg@3Kuc2lUvYvo590BdyDLNVpuHC3uVqoYHYSHiK4fo9/6MkUUSpFtvhIUb9q5okOR3@4//g8M48PhAs2eVdFJ4Vq5E9DNBZF4PeOQW4qteie/3BV8v4FcAG1Fnlu7iUzona2MYDblWcv2K4fubP1QtJvggxpvJJXUsp5pbyJ2Mv7Bnlsuq6Vg0vxb@hTP8RzZSZea6CKMcVLl4fvrXyTK1uymuk4W@b1irM9O03A7/9H/nUR/rmNPqgQdwQWtPVe5aWdDmf/fvDf5p4cb0CoL52z/5@S@SPk4X9my6sD8/T1bTdL4X00Vtv5HZkn6AI6O4Ml04FX@Vria1cqee9bkIwV8uGvdperCni5Y8kb5Z9NMrlv0iJD/TSMyCn1655Bfh@n2NK3exZ7u1YLlPFy5zjX3BQs/gX17QTFqMf24vxullM79wzS8mi//EyMHwwXh0blrqdcXhNJi1ve80@S888@LvRrY19u6Hq7aEcfGIoyJ0kJpStAeo6X175Z9nY8pfCF@TpDaVswXdI6uWpqqFRJP2IMqpyvO@sbpWMXQk7uXUsvFhlRQu6vWhL0b3k1EPUge/352y5DHm5z8ED8jfGX@H55K4bRJXxNqG3RMccJMP@QUnmiMfoGOfQ1rUgAfoHokb/Pe@6W61KSksb9zIYhmEwhLd4Ot0iEILBRElSaw0D3OFCpFTcxfCfzM7kEhXHZGuMFiqj@xHNsm5cvP@vV@YHcmMUpjGnkG5cjXOP1XTwCpG/FbOHjsUT7cYtZf6MoJUOlUfAQuP7v9u7xaZ6hbzkhbYIsx/8K/MQedH0GXtUX9g8soe/xEcEwOz8AS09k/5yQjc8nKyZSys@V/riY9kh1pUOU6ya9SzoJo/@2dFkHb@IEl262ohS2FcKGM5O8@cly@295zdl/vPX@7jQsZ2jGhk8MWCnojdsi@zAJu@JJiTZVsk5q@KOGvlCXkFlWBltczd/7c/R/cF7YpXbBStYbq03B@lyjV1uUvGiKfi2iOkxmeuvFxaUOukbtVbz1tTI0QC9M4wxnqNfPqhwORiQhw@q7NNyF9Mpm2pW1UseK4x9d9kt6zLmMWXCTjqMAFe08H8eY3vKOPboQy@sprh9c7Le80T/NQL7fKTQb9tCkrdbOZf@J6dndX6CE81GQc1P4J7ogiO4eqjY2IWhiFfasJtNhFe0CXZFs4LJ903ya9qtz18246gIPPZFCrR3r1PZvK3sOiOeHR8KqE4PvSe2HH4trcyq3QrhKzS6b6p9M96LZUhhsFG4UQSwf2M9cdppH8Fo76BCGPcs5uszuBNNxwwt1vsDOggKyZVSw815Ex/qu9RIIYx@hJ5pryfOsw0u6JI4eDRgHPoJ3FV2ro4mB7MDlPFp6Z4SpslkoiYlyIVhWDkix4Hhw2YSv40qVRXezBVzuKNCRleH6AUoiGBZqZhUhbhyJmKUvwGXqiQBshZKg2WP12PS@vxli@aR08TBtHEiAbcd@sHX746eHU4jPyz5cOV@nEFjo4A3VFmjTym7LNHfmP0B28HozBKJQ39KBYFl4ZO6p4oahBaEcUXNVYZjRtqllG4CZJBg3agx5nYoh/EbqDMVFkb54Sft4sHxWSMpWEHqjEY6UArGag0PDxZpvY2okMLEdJNl3QkvjxdqOIXY/jT0rBVGnM4gBnOYEaIQA3ppaJimDoX6VbhtUwSaNjFB26mKzqfpuIgk2V180LNv938m@/d/D6ti/zWM8HKpphRGpv6tOH6armIR8wNz5pXakF9uT2Ay7/i9pDd02jFwXJrua5NU6QedEEFnbUmv6scT8hL6lBpoaCuGWRfZ@bJspR1oYfUaJokr/CcrwlBlZcNRCKI5BTzVbGpXYwkXdk4@Fksr9iZ1cgpN3IqRQR6uqCRh6oYAnnabhsO4bStTecR4WuKRi@LhU7Ufov4VOKKaLlu6kz2HKYCbWFIEwo66x7m1n5gNdratDIIQIhzCHp@vz0ZxOuF7IbXrJovs0fJUOo9Sr4UGcheQQTGW3BLlMpcQ2TqxQJX6QG7vaRfB4Vis9KoNPl/Dfl/saIT9f@b84mNNGQzndioZP73G0k8xMjmi0XNxm1syIVfLTmjWXwSDlcLS445sx0@s@GPUF5QX0fyPhwNg9HIjznMkXPsD/G4jcCvQYgbCzj/Qlwd@v3GZ/8i6xq5I0@xR6@jIyA6Uohqo5lT/GizSON@OgrHsfPVIOjo34hRfve2/opmEdxIRb7PPFBETJB65oa@7/54thPvDnEvUYfH5DiU351B2Kmfkijvj9mVY0RrniCCsDaeDOvsbsof9vAszmYI7TfUtBOqjrrWOyKwI3TLLYPyIh/uKYuvpv1@kZ23@IPeCx@MG26PHBNJZafHfEc7OiliW1tynhETti7uVrQPE@Oli0fcd0rqMa46kHjOrDFQsiJ9QeMdsSxZM6MIpWj1Xs@u/4o1foCmUsUys2VumU/EME7gtSqnKiCKIakS6COC9AljjLMi6RFChPqwLFGNWHEclcDtSD5VpUkCV6TO56BC7CF6pa1ofZemVXjG5jrce@KuzGuWzU4RwE6qubaO2BzcEwwopkk9DTfXkMMOKiMHEefEN43djxVPtYQAZUI4ECLx2GN4ZOi8ZiVSXNbR4QH6q@k8XE904BJtwDFecH819I85Sopz1gkkFEwviBgAJevHXwUjNUSVFKl2JsfEavNa4MgqQRRN/Dufrt3mBnFcIw3aC7sp0NU6YYZr2To37iQ@HZhe3ItPnIH/1h@I/zdpNsd@kUXJdOaq7RPXzXfLTDo0lKme0ii49yqStrX9@MmD/e2tilNt3gG4GKgaWNcaXMle4Xw24FBkhCKyfGudu7eFyN2oUtqsl8qq6Zv2sK/YDdYIaM8aQ44buSWPi6mbOUFMIlMPe1XFxFs0sd2gq43lhqZMxohaUNSDq1f@0lIRJI26lkCCqc2RypSTQ4O@aOOZA1q4V9AIqN3tCEIYQgkx5Rbv36xWzZpa519V2lir1Q2xMy8@Ijn8jVPamwxTu22J107bKdEmB295srXdLPG@UCu2nBOv9HFUaoE7N5zTW3dSPtch/oZ9tMKVgdsPH870/LkTrbVCA1I@aB6Wyyqh9P/@L4l9F4lZwMCNy@fgr7/ytEvYmmzq2@JB0y3JbTAV@6oW@9P4EW@usRe3TIFO2JvVOCRp7xGdvT33K7uOkVs@Z@3mrufdKp9TleMR7FBGtBn6@4Sx3EJaP5WWiByvXg3hFncZ8tcPnj75nKZ8D/6lovjgy8Plj@qVUomOeNZA8hDpw9naffocNwnjco1vFB6Pw1M1LuO2qaSGh31YDnPrK0V0rY5VSDvnsR@r3kcPZ/vt42ftU5KY2zQE6Quctq31gzD30OW3x8grpie3WD4/9hjqZOz3W8IJXUTeW/e43Irpz4ldxR2qwltdZewxFfLgQCAz6sGQTuvP958@8Ur32w6wejmrorTSMcRBhMIE4yKJBdoU6SCcLqgqFrtNJhj6t1IqbqT7cr/e3ii1Li4WtudJ2O6Jx69SQsA9d1JRFDf25qe0NU6oYDbyPSTI0fa97f1ihcpC9kUixzia8aYlzog9XYeQG3YKPgJnLwDjebc/@YTTUGQSed5qo1GGesgFYWMfEIRWFta4dTFuez3XDGR7FNT46tyfSl3MnKzWVuvtYXRG7Gi9ebdx71bjs3CMd4OeH3U/iWgL8doIKRvEs09gyM/qZMfhoP9JPxjgwerm7eW13eDhP/rBvRd3t9xu5x8QD1l8HYV4wB@P7AaM22dK@4/22HFXqIsbMSSc3XZ91H4T1m/3Gt21xlrz057/6R1/rXFrrXvHv3Wvc@/evW7/9lqnd@/T9qd3up063EZzkdopKw8WhfxRbf961S5izNZWG/f6/Wbz7qe9O/f691Ybt27d7qzd6TVu3@6vNdu3bt3tra517nUu59qS9hRog9X7Ls6O7A788WLmrjC3t6vS5f8P';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`《`《\》9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #en =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]>84576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t};prescata, 8 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>          K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@   A=AgRA;       AC
#   /         
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[x]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s》say 27#》say 167#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint ("65" )#`=>ass#
#9'>+/' 25  pe+--[red[ ]print 221;};]pppppe^ee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*ss<s*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

I used [this interpreter](http://www.rebol.com/downloads/v278/rebol-core-278-4-2.tar.gz). Command line: `./rebol -q polyglot`.

Pure Rebol code: `rebol[]print 223`.

Code in polyglot is on lines 207/208:

```
rebol[x]print 223
#s{
```

plus `};` on the last line.

Everything until `rebol[]` is ignored, `rebol[]` must be at start of line (barring whitespace).
`;` starts line comment.
Multiline string `{...}` is used as block comment. `{}` inside must be balanced.

There were 2 sources of unmatched braces inside Rebol string – Perl6/Sidef comment and BitChanger.
Perl6/Sidef were changed to using [`《`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300a/index.htm)`》` instead of `{}` for [embedded comment](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Embedded_Comments).
Note: [`〈`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2329/index.htm)`〉` and [`⁅`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2045/index.htm)`⁆` break Braille for some reason.
Readded matching `{`s to BitChanger code.

Trailing spaces on line 205 are for ADJUST. `x` in `[x]` is for Incident and Retina.
`#` in `#s{` is for Flaks.
Fixed Ursala by moving `[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf` above Perl6/Sidef comment `` #`《`《\》 ``.

Comment: So I guess Red inherited the "undocumented feature" from Rebol. Very convenient :P

Answer (score 6):

## 229. [Puzzlang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Puzzlang), <s>10918</s> 10741 bytes

*-175 bytes thanks to [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%c3%98rjan-johansen)*

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rb@NKliD42Zr9B/slTPmmJOtF6mXJspQpv9LOdNpOP9KZaesqKYmSaFMkk6RsKZ2@qK5Z1HZNNxY9NbWNfuzMre7Znu3dGWAai12gB9ODAbq/DhrzG7I/LRqLrX9Qe84JkqJk@ZG3qrGzwNAWGYw4cSLixIkTJ16HTdnu/epXYbzYvqGNuprhMEexHda21EvFSrHVEXsmq3Y@kw2FEKpmdQd9RXfs5VCYSYypekttwztzjAtFVz8pFvhnGDMto2vJfeb0ZIcpdks2FZsZA8ccOMzozI6WZWyjb5yrSYzZV/UugDmKZVqKQ@E5xo51Te432/JUSH4qQdOCcJutK9rn/meHtYx@X9bbNkAWGHtlWLaC8C3Ftg2MvsTYcENpTSEtAqhsqcZObff5VFCJseeQRdnUlCGTm7ZjyS1HNXSkicgOd48P96diSBJ7c7S5Oe2bYS@Ths42B62L6aAsO7ZsWZOn8edYbeAY2860f57Vuoous0yqlMpMBxbYqiXfirLELEVud1RNSUGFsCTrKZqpWAx9WMew2DZkSSuKRbFRG8dMtTBucRw4jbbEtGzWmSpPRgTCG1ZP0SGH4nSg5AdOBWT8gLZKCcjWiEXtnmEBH1lsYCttdmVYbWAuXRvFEhCfDT@xpmwrhRwiyPoILnTjSgcmcgyo2ubIUZhu6EmKjIA5Ju00phkrk0ff2t72tH@BZXam/ZaA0VoXndt1mSmyA8McTfuW2Ct1ZxY7Z0XeENaMNtTGVJjE9mXwomQmCZ/NTLaCFtQuNGZ2bkPG2gqzddU0FYcHAq8oFgVDbKap@gViyLITVbHa02nm2P7g0ydNhia5ZvRNYA@Li4N9y2gPWthUnZ4CsbB5I/fYoRakUWWmK1RS6GBh4jcOBmgPjb4STMlmugLVaZtKS@2oLc6GytBRdBsKaKeYCkW@UjWNtRUNIoyxtxLMNpAZxl5NTe6lWqkQsjGmwvoXGlNZyzQZD4IyQ5Y2xSJTkNbsE4RrPZsNzT6z1T4EOy2j01EU9kkxexA91DZCDK6WOVUs/21BARhd8UijmCA@kDQG1gvQyaPQlSVDRVi2SwNH7UM1qE7EZopsqyh@IYqt6G2iqukLZoPJEw2EXaogHqDoA4tw24pFDZTwQmO2FEAp@0wRvbJUx6E2xmpsX5EtdmQpSmxSSE8kCYkZmIKDBUlRpa6sRDb2NiNQuTxGSjahMq3s0esXIZmlKmyhUYZfRRDKoY3ddXa9cIZuLpOBAUwrKsdY5Ttmp8/OFPgNpWa6a92EAGsIqKKxtGE6aTlpQgaTDmQwLaMTXcnLTMrUAgmzlam6CLAch2pDbYCoYm8SVLLWwLKw3xkTVb6AQmuG3gV6QmGtgY700FlBhCpoGdBtJJhyCVQDOU11BFIEKXzUU6HSbKySQDPkvScRFPpPYGOXol66tqENCA5i2g7yMlAFoiLG7Q57wzqyqmEUCEdUPNeWYg80B@MM9DbWPPSOSjvFvGxQ87aAjy8hORmQkgewfj/QLilTAAwVYVBRMejL7/1xu9sFPLVWCyShy65vWNtoUT8vU2ah82TIsCB@NcoWwCUwdR4dEriUNbVN4kTWR24SlAlK9coYaG1mQILWlQqttCdfQsuGxtVyFM7kXDVIsL58waWJyjkXCt6Xm1CxlAClTcVOsmdrUEstJRQmnkn2B06nyJLmBovY6W@jT5ejT@fPFMhcLBVbXEinu2VguNQiecFb5D7OeVObkKu2I9uG2g6ZI6dn6BmWbDGhVTFMRY9GJnBEEhGrGYmlUMpFY2W10kp1VL0djawAL1Yh4Uis3Kq0TtXlenkqejBJQHOFaLC5KtFWTAiByKFGcZnug@xPQVfyJum6AmGG3UCSY3Aq4I2Emfa75B5hUo2QLw1kEJBDKVtTFDMqpqQYigmEm1luDJhV0ikcboGX1Xo8Eo7Eg0UnDFDSiYJiYz1SDRRbmtnDLg6IotvU4yDvtqBfR8loqw7opwnWJL6mXgQkC8nEKyViKagA@HxETZI3OYyfREHpYhg3ocmWrLQDDRmEALRlx74ljTXjChKkPGE3A6JDx0TlLlQNROYFqfGC8JTIZ7JIXC0BbE2FFZNNFRoBNjeQ6S7PB8oG4NkMhwFsvJEEZE9fHgGWFu9Wxw2GqR1oS30QD6A7tRSUOSB8FN6hYCIDan82aOSom4vJTD4/2cZuNTHHSteS70FIf0rf25Kw8MHGhIKGdZQrhrrEQO4qXG9jcqulmI4rqKAktgOiaLq/Ic@k23mm7F5o4dl02tSJeKrFOA0U8rz23K5QRuniDguSoPwoTHYHNqBnWiCWtNF06gBwOZW48AFBJjLwQbgjC54GAEymDJXWwAGpBgx81VNbPeBZzJ3O5SLvhKaTB69g6iDZkx0/acyMVH2SCaXSvhdm404USazR23igc0VU1QkPqvygx/2YZbs/A7HhZxE6goBvKi2ngPcewNk3dGMGUiCkjxZBJkN4PYAmdogKJXRcntpFjdXXMv0qgjrDYUMb@a/nOKa9DP2E6vQGzRRwSvrIGm07ezoyS9qxRqpjcHdTM5oglm1on2kvhXRr0FSHUwUiP78Oz@3QJShgHZtVoOf@OACui0Y6NghM8l9D4ECQQIKbUPC7AIAElAJCRTs2ieJNECqHI70VFSaYUkgwAduuAOMjASP6pHmByttkNs/BazqXCBbMTCqNUGnbapEjGdBJET2CU7ZCcxNFe2QeQ3OCALeOrNkKPPWBpuHrQOdSLsp1hRi7Ds3NgWiLUnJq39TUluo03EmGJ0@86Yb5SoXUpg7qTDGIM@eO/VMgUADG7X44dMoxDknZjcagIHM3EwkrlmVYPF2nZxlXjDwQLBQkqjtEYiekcKEGDYNvVccRm9uXUlcqz1Qh/D6V9OVIJHVuqHr0OjI/Px9ZjlShx5yffwquFXQ9RVccXE/JlSQXwqXQRTES5MLQU4qBfvXIzamHeRirY3MYYm//STWj8unycraekE8l95nBZwzoDD0GQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYUL2CgqaancnSr2Gvd9iyVNMlwgv5UubvLhWyRAaoOBzMW0oZlZf7adKvWKBdwGCg1YtakbNT8ax@dn3Wjp/dRBIYO1aWK00oFKQX7ae6ljEANSR2mltOSvVY7DQLykezEhEji9FoMalBQnIs9k0xFpc5taMRBXrD6NlZBIjq0ue01bMI3zCRicV8UkE@UOEBXTsaSV0XIf1mrB6LRyBuLJKAoVslEgHKtJAINhUa29IEgfYOXnLCrMXjIWrehnWBv1vdKfilYODKo2@CXFg7nJx86F9Ar8VatoYqXtLiWh68phe5Z5sevia7zLZpJKCDGgMlAC2m7Y84cU4EW5w3aDCCCdEwGyHID/t07K/UCRhE3FGHMPACeTryFEzUi1DHXIOBvKEpqRNqcwIDcYGTD0pqppa5z7vrVMse8wDok@A0NbkFUmUS3ZnAzgAh8Hk6PTskVr6FeFoFpdHiQ2WEDrsl60i/tkqjoYFq95C8oLGirLE6QFUcCoHOpRDVtlkLdKkuUFoZqg4fGwEfHWKULdmOxlAbr3FtFpVo1MQwU97cCqlJRgvGkQpoZBjKB@VsQ79ULUNHIqc2ADUwfBnrYAr5LPICG9Vq25n1u@k7CzlQ7Ja3FKBtEOs0cVt2i6V1QzO6BlsEAGTNVIoz9raOE1agSzswbGe2@okIVOsa@miKBxVUo2zUvaVC1h/VyAiZJvjUOcgaNrvQY4A7yny4/X4DOjspL4qQf@9NpMsvZADLdBnRs8XGAO7EuYZ8gzX5XjF7o4lpPeQPPjoHfjIU3jD5fIkMigrkym3hnyhqsJFzH2jnXlDbc80q@wZpnjhFFBy9TZR@ok/kzQZKGJ7yRl@PFBNIb1X4uH5RcJ2lJ@SWPyBNdvqGI6ffpHo2w1sI9bCkygQ7HZmPpJNJvAsUxDJVlm4rl2mUUi5mkMpHvYESUlo9gwlnoBMGgQQQoT0Y3CShENBjoyLpR3OXCEKOMQA9vK1oal91tmmCUtNR2UyRHEyhAHBDcVZ2jGBfVUCD4iPEseDGScSxFNe7HP4AhCJhhTFZipfcUtrpRR66McSO0A4p9GS7e@sbjf3a0VZFSA9sK62pTWg5baXRh4GEptgCm74wAUjKjf/pQjswDKfC2eRCYw9eYYzjRd9Zb@xsrx7UDt7xTBAaW@0PNBmzsrwwBYDRDymYl2ZPa0/O7ZLSPTEmcpkaNcgyA02bJZNwT6IfpUY6ZgoDsMNHMZxM4pyWjLN2FstIYqnUbsrFolJot3K5pY7cabdzGamY7xTzmbwIt6VCSWGfCTyZVIY0DgUXH@PhcBjTgJzTQ0rl3CyJebkpKTMzxYPuyZbSLraK@bysNHOtlgy5ahWySq4jiqWckskouWauI8lSJnNvtngqXr8Oan4L@unRzAz5offkqZXPK0u5klxqlUolObPUzsqZ4pKiFJY6OVFUCpLYaRalYvbePAWygQrF@K1Po2toIDgQo8CxSA8ygGX0/WG27bbVhSy2TmVi2Q/nnNzQHIYO3EW/gH8B/fu4kJdqhbqtFksa/NX3dAGXEBAX90iB6sbjCEmLfb6nC1kklLjgl7KanmcJPf2lvolFsDG6WeF3R3IxX0viDSK39YFtBkp2LUnkf@l0Oqgy@t4Z8r5IopzVxt5Z8uZLhZOLdC5ZbgXNBPbx5QgfX2Kcie9W0ExgH1@e48OlydnopkJmgfrICoQMlzJn4poKmAHoY1oiTMHlz3FYkcLuWvt005oZfGckH3eJcOP66BgVrZa6Xh5ghnNHn69d2g1c@BjzSEaaCMUgvuLJkm0Yyq8gCPLLZ1wLBS8YQthmO@UMnTGKbBBFEhRevhLqh3NGkLSG3IBWOc6t5xMIYkkN@jipMI6c9yMbU1ENdeztg/N6zWgNEAGDQJP2fIJBfiRehd6Sa7BRZHgNWoY5CrTl6wwnfl91xUmgdWU5uUkOoWpuTQRyapvesutEGG@WfKm1cc5n4BvuSmuwyrKc3le4vEpDQRKQR6AP7higxe@oNm2MCErMkD/aPAsJ3pB5ctJkHJIZLwmw5OXstQwhiIg6DxC3FwZ2yGNXQ0xJecTio@hfaLdjdmDAQ7cJ0FuZuh3CFYl@s0O3GQCo5EzPQlEATfG5WhOMi@T0AT1wsm9WDianLSeSbyqdAYzF0k1VR/cDYMlSkSA7zaZ6FyhQAhepvecMsGV2MIDxcCaVS0ne4BuXCaAP5XOOR9t7BAgtuXdrrptNEN8ZWA7Ecp//6UdtqITbVdSTRzQi9R0NXbki/ujcWWNuVHyh2@za5erZQFNlIgy5HkLZknF5UdZ8x2zUVPvJZE@2@jjwc6sbGBRvwAn38BrPuaVog7biPWcnssyIyJNz6kxX@6w1A5pgp6b/eWI01NcMuU1k4ANyVaFIFlY2rwZlyIemAXUYxNJdCc2YpWfjZXGnN3AG/I4r4Q9Vo2ri774mmnV1zbRhy01Vuae@Lfli0DaS5kWXSot5KsyAHRe8ibOeyY4mX3BnA52zS87LZqndrmJ5z7vArnowuKRRcfqKHvewhKddMRo0yffhtDR@vwvE27LmO@6mk6rR7RE17HMS8Qbo00Ra3OeSDJBJnSKsJjdHODvQ@3qWwgRJbQUBU2nF42IW@1l/UXO8o8Y0746PnTPFL5Vmx@Y7bDhJZo1d03xnTZLPjFKZ3b02D7Ru6KXUvqwlM@2A807x7c26j10zQGmqKNnSZBuYyXGrQ7mE6qPbfQyO3VAL2Wrsuoe9x9nx1rbvWiZ1ZZTbhFuGptrYjrW7xOX0ytI4TdzjRLdxVHy7Tdg2acJ2L@m7ZksCo@XgGuUdjPYIkcaXB3EBNsA5KeMuorWMK/zdqUf0jEuF32f3ap9m5uoRMiqpEUuorZndR7v1EKfiPhe6zabjxcx8OS1tpr@7ajQ5GngsL9uqZtjskO73kQIUbNvm99lcHKSaKutJWtwIumdHczNlspQ7mXtHXcpa19AKxW5ahtudFT6wOij53edjJZ4vsSTpYYnlKUCGLrnPO0X9Rdq6eIgTaAXEwhXogPOefnaW2HJX2O4uIAwVcFvJ7MJtikWKmUrzOZK7KsBq9a7kkff8Ab3JXdT1ehNzRAo16HcYoVQEh2NxJfuHpJa7P7X240TSLbRLDxUiULkXmgKdF91vVSnLiNJXxpBE8fECqqMNlIEyUz7tNc8V3IZ8zzDj8ZkS3WIsuFPKaSAeTij7UJ/cAeKjco39Nr7dK2BkTYVG/qB2M1PemaCEmzim3gfHPjpuR@zqA3OicieGafrB/ZTrmV7LNtoTmcSQr5VIxYd1qAmd3lbod9fABjIZsXH7OAyNjT4oDzpfDATRAyRSm5rCrlQgFd@9gptU7ZkzAzQVwu8TSZHPWPWYmDGZkaHx7DRUrnphJ3Ge@HHyJ3PXoJ6AS6W0DgVwRni/i@iz5GnTMLSvqSQQq22VTh5oSdw9/lBl3dJ43M1LbDx9YePkR7Nz18QF73LcASZQD8fOzj2j5eDE1D3jvFuT7Pd0XIEp94fGmNBp01wQbgZy3XfxJk2ASKliaune9sUVUqOpaDJ/DAu5@/CVUtl78fkKiKvp0ioervzxtb7xMmx4SgqZIyCW2oZhSk/pK/R6j34vt88Htve4E2ho4G9GcCpNyxJ3xDNVaPY63ifWFQOKkWPoMLByZKur4MhEw6V01/cuUeutdswk7nZf7ir8YNJ9snA8M4G7Wvl4buycPUexzDdEtSAa3y9yPytAw7lQRrb3nInw1agF9TnoPzyzNtXGW3Sq5aFGnUrPXOR5QPPTe0ZP7yk9ixqH/3ZX8wCOdPiRsvsKAfnvyfYFbuMleTQe2PXsIHU1Q9MeQ12Uh1w6GkZnZr428AhOG6J@Fd6R3IQA9/HgrB303kQk6sbvajs9ZQBdkm04hqkk6e0uUA3nffj9LqnpzcQ/ZvaoqRky7gm/R2MHGnjPx2BsGdaDkx1d2XBMkx4NUxvYdKP52yQdjZpVV5uU08dUu@rwDUmcOZWu0Wz11Iey1FRkR1cv0t7EDX@9dzDqil0qucqS6@id0lSglTVKYXVXguGH@Ni@q84CSzczS782sKzRwyJgcjOIP7HK1wPQcVf67qLsjGDq3HHHnbez7J5FCXcN905uIq0ZNeSkIoL@Id057TOxudCVU7SYeId6M1Vuykxg/exr5ivdnSA0c6cG9rqA/6wZi7tE3pYryWAoGN0adO3Yw4zba4P2hLeZCGtdPE1pM8cwmK0ZV4HZZehwZN19zOx//dXG@xY88veueKTS7hpnUhncOaWlqabN7yzZyczEcnvR/jbUaPbw1q2ettLhixLoekiH6xsWnlwBZSHZshS7hdPcKGe5ZsRFjm50Qd4mNTYG9mBnFuH2PoFZWshkX5Z8u6t0ZdxxuaPi5kvNvt29AebpLQOPQfx6INvq64HhKDNxTm8deAzKV3JXbW1N1IKH0KOuuz2PPyYaAXrdroirnmrTAQLPMbvhcDajVfgZQ66pmXT/IOv9sx8BDcjdb8yS28zbl@w7cC4fw@WZaU3ql@4C/J2CTnVoltR9zizn7G0W900dXA365sB2H7NTpw1Lweni/gX521cqSMHkRxC6rCdrzuwp5cCMKWhObk84dt6lT79XNaPL3hdFBooWCDhUr@9grFXol/dlB1qAPoNZKf1HrlLihETS4oX7CIygZFlS1VXn/skXx5FhxOM9sUBcqcLjbukdvKeefS2G5NFsquzcK/GhSx@1NBjDPAS1/@4BCGXt4a7lgbUW6CoNfeAk8YjwfV1E4d4uYpkNi4UAD7Do641XxzGPFbq9Ft/m@oAmZiswdhvY2mjsunNpfwaHqWhI4W4hezuGNwhYVzryQHMOcBnvMfFqJp7LIZm@bswarOyPoIv5qhEP9BKD/rrSwuW/R@Vh13gF6hn0WyZI1f6Bggv1U4Lk7sgYdcdoyRrQrP2o5A4J/YxOYTxWlk2lCXWvjV2z9a@7kK/LjjyLmArO@3UeGrQv42pQU7HOuX2JeyFv52BLGdIo427u4WpO0mm1uEaN02gTjSYwsoa8mAafpLwnFzXoBr56aJ/C3dUTHVuy9Sga713yXR1Km58Fs2eR@kBpGtrDMkVX@aK@bKmKnd5R9cGQ/FgS9LLZo5gXJDnEB2bJaAjg7qzRL2WbFtjvGhhxlBIaXnlwScDbr9OTrZaBi1au4y4d3jcNcg9qd/872VbwT@HaCfeQA/iplntcz055djbCdCCEzuR6W8ZZGE8KD3Do4RhWihFcNCrH47FYiEfCNduuDmAeFFk6wFPQ3IiCzUDCOwSrdtjpKVu4Hi6Ly9INqzBhWWD1OseKF53J3RiaZKbggEc/XZDrlYVIMhlZiJzpy0yM@OCKBkrMTHB5Araj0oPnd0wCpsv82A@6vRKX@Slvu0cWFGDA3oaB/7FOU@44icDPKvOD8Ee4G@xv/rztGpboKlDYvgoDCSAI2lUx@krPuHrK03VTB/Eso2EKxAE6p8aPSSfXagyUIQf6bpufEGPHm0dF95S6a8QFXvb5CNLPBa9cnI3Gs1AOrzyeG/9ci5uwH8srFHS9g77OrtS207NTIKHomNPAGm8ZBxeC6Y6FU1DtBNtmbQX34tDpNZp11Qzjgk4aYE7@5s/52Xw6w@aeLfKSJ5scgRTxqJpEB@JbLWMAufaQfFIswwWJIpFBAx3gegZDpYT8Y3iyi4wGAEcmvSPzlAw/N79WO2TJDRZB@zR4xLWsdqILtYPnb07FeuU71k8r/@lH6di1Szjhm2SpYAsJ5oGUb5CxgsF5CB6HRpiwMBR4gv4BP9XtUq94fQCJZM5keMbP4zHDMN1WQ2ZPyMqHz43u6dkouqmevbPzfbKYQgyrXNEiEh1/0bFDRVMkug0NDF5jhJq3uspCdMCn3ZOHDstDgmh/QAYXt7FCR97wHDhGWRiyz6yHTAbyWsqL8MYJqaHpgX5l1duWmQ1ul02vK80B7Ru7zKQy2QoVZ6FRWamSC7oCA02AnH57NsyIybPh0kY9bXtEPTsbfiNm3gLVDQtiPUljy9vYXb9eSFXFz59tecQE4SZS5rt5QUwsXO9v728cHtWOjg@hFm488bPJD114sga5iA5W9QyNjKsAXbAj@Ar547/hUecoW5DZChoZi8VCwbM7BOrSWkgKC9wZEE0TsR@IPiu@rQTCbwO4Mq2jMo@jtqEbwDoEZkOqYeEHJpqIYW5c18wFcZmKMh4bkE8Y3DM9Q5YSqQRWAWIlgViPJBW7u7BPud9jKPYglvvJ9nQmCFLMT@/UD@dFnEmCm99IuU3oKH/9cnMs95ebYO4pN4D6vl6czdr2zvHBxmQ04DF6ktStlPLuoTUunLGl8aV4z64HnSt2I@KSRUVgAkXgr25nRhbkmopzpUCxXOHY6vPIxKGUfyE0ZkygTAXN8NXLnBbRKOUAdZAyFmvqTF1HHQay6PXRAXTXvIi@ENgUfNRexlOCizlMRs5SeHnFQKwuubymt09C3JXXETuo/iS8FodFwz56YPM2d0dX5fc6NoP/QK/kuTJ1NmRudybVWZJl4KcpehcK7MHGyryPYgucEMICz7vg5xcNbEGe2ucyzSfStl73xBj00ppsojUfF3rXcJRl9nFg0NloT5j4@sUVzlbJ3JYcVW1LxtLQmWvdQcs8Xr9F@LY3DyuonXHVjOR7kOcGOnZUABSw7LaBh@OA2fgBO24jipPccM0ReV0l7bSwXfMjvpZgs0vVpp0YWAkd1HE0kJRYGrfgaISRTsWzmmaDTtKG7pubLCTlJEWnSvjRkqTOhDDwZMpXGRNMCCGsXbltnga60isYjLU@8MgLBEeY7QDOyMp8MgmU66q6ZzRwGa0I0gLCMnOsAW7hqkZuRfGysEyuZM/pawHAGYa6zpT0l9/7Y26c68wB909d91Bchbffcd864P5dL0SS4O2f@m8ZePsZf/s2jVV22yKRm7w7fXLnWR3gy2fCrTKhTPAsJ1JZ/NrGmn6zvc9sWszDuuzLw0A1oYRBnoMxH/BfH5jikuoYwXkK4yoc44mevgEWAb4C/kD1BjUaSk@x6lG0S7OcTmPGccYxRcc6lCFfySMzNR8HaJ4NlLB0IV/ISWnIZPLSQ0g2Dbp4sIAjjMWWQSaGLlWz8qHZwpNjTLBbsqZUCmXOG@kF@dus8MHP6ALAhvhA4ZRBHDxs5seAsKobLbogx6UYRsWOLCJFUKa1Dc5qoA1GyQEgMfTWvaPboG4aLqmAj3Vl6JDGNPIGQE002okrEAo30uchSgIijhuNiE03x/GJATxMFWigqWA1CCcIdohgy8IsZj39lp05Z3rdNSbHgPF@MYN1dXD/kxkW5jhnoZWH26bNotOGybA07NmhbuD8wybklkUz6Uw2LRViAQ4VXFSQX2zqnwElNG4QFi1FPTdMu7a2sf1ib//wlokugoxMg0VYpLoSP0umEqd13xHx8z1J1NXN9OGr1U2PlMFcjXdcIcR429V0NmelNp3TO1I/4Uc1bqdNAbcSksTHIqY9DslN2qB4G/s4NB0AXOM7xW@lGo1d35zWV6pnevhW8p9nmS0MpxaRucB1ZpPRwsh0NjGL294BlCM0nmynvDOGGWFslNM/Qsnfx953G9nyTTGPLW15R11CZFFhbHUhdcchGCh7Ks2TInNIPGNefkHWeFmVMKvjBFuhW7vmgrlhblluW412z4P6RNrjc0iezV@bQ9oknPksE5m782nmwx15GLHpj200ucaJepA7TW2Grlw7Gt5pWt@GRso2NdWJxkK6CzF9rvY2pH2vqSMfTK6cDpl/ENRGnXGYopWYKFlovKqHuKUo5hl0ipNNqP0B0G3fMNl4Fm1d8VwHoFOx9QGfmVfYi0Ef4Dr0OFCwt1BAy0pCZKBnxMvKKVpBcimR6rfz0WEs1VOGbbULPU40lgDR9I0kja1JyWgOCfSq5qwS4LSU2ZOhDFg12RU0xjSMrZTodVxAPp/IrmZ76/UQIMOozdgyn7mIHOueQUWs@GUWSfiUacYSkRTjIynXViJtjKWJqBRb6@GWaZr66HRUUtmCNlp4Z95RrX4KSwXdDGeh53hgIsg1X2XYK0AZ@VROqXpbGUbRhspyHekE/pGrk8tITLjF4mRdzLUl1Z42M@bJQtlxhdLYRNeUvCuVfDk3KRpKJbTDgkeKYVACKR461g44QUWIdvqyyaID2kFssxSj1@hZVE/YjhVjySp211dMZ/E4zWnAgwJgzIKgHXKpZBAniuZio@kKVBL62nobH59Uk51KqVQd3JRIjC3gfOYaaFM4ExgLwRgVoiwTWtAv4G8Zc8RNgadck@ALlGyITCUxNAI3I5jkFC66gXwBWlCpWfVJwMTMWMBwqpZKy25tTEr7EgO@WJkhEAHtDCnujRGAvu4JUaAaymiAWrOUtgry8tlLRdcVIBDwTB8tn8sDYDIrlvCM8ifGZnAphTDP4pZ75BQyOmkedyNyreFa1kK6TFNj5RtQaz6coV7TcTWbUfq/TafS5evoglYZpUHXjFWjC72KFM8uxuML@mJ0QUdt68kTnFG7WQBlrpGCAeoQgJILWqwM/AzKX2VBLy/IK9GFdiWzSDHgFYbI1xDhOzudul6Qb9ILT0BZSoCPxYVOdMEmC2tiKiXdQP6whSykE8Az12gqjEztY/ILajyOeUgtNDAD36XPDuPUbZ4dpmnyruyOBdLdvtvcplQxvyZufSKAE9D1XvY7rDx2WO7W4YYHPDaOm50Vdof6xxN@iWctGO0WU@zg4EuYDHm8YHHlNMpcV8hEuYk7IOAwCkTE14Qci4Ew@dWvwlKBMeFpIRs14k/zYjkeyUswTIfxdfgZ6OHpRcESrs/Wk5dM6WQKH5Oncif1sb5/sb//NnYWZSUWCa/tCVJO@Ba/hvC4a4ll7rjYD7/C4cV0KJxelJ4spdMfPnyAEQdcp9VUFcQHv2KnyUj9NLrEWHVpaTFRKC4mnkUagWzFoplM7JCpapqdqabdbsPP6NF3MaJhfj19SmnB8B/@Gfdz03cd3guCuL7hr4S7lPNhdrYky4vxXOaZXk5lxMzf/OX8TeJ6v7HyN7/VTyvz@NjDx09vXqH7UMp/Mz//zepqLpcAQnL3/vv9d7VaLbeeyO@f5p/mkuL8yl//h/n5TGYlk56v27ZUj5xevBUyYk5I/c2fRvb3XzdsGwhRwivLJHDivQg/ieXz7IJ9guuiw/Cf3J/aAbeM7mbnE5q1g/FKhYRNJJLPRg6/jcyutnkmVZ8u/eef730MO@FqJn1iwdMJfwwXimHuBAe8Zb23y3A1vIJghZvwKF2pVMC59J//LcSvvgA8GDJagVs17@EqjMLVZIWifA5XC@CQMhlI9//60Y9C4eow/CksSVJ4RH8NdMNVfCI9YehIC0tFwTCe4UdO8BoGrnEp0pKUOfPqM1DdWLW@dw9wQ70yI@Dn17vPVczlBnI8Fq4Ktw28/vb/@Ns/@Nuf098f0O/f43cbCvPPPqwzpkAPjNfy8rNb9bAz9X6QSsKV8ltHGF@TbsnCxUqiwXPls3A44Jiig39nLkn896@EC4U9O@Uoh@rslT6ui7OwVMztPZuooOEDds7C/sXcZHyS@omzaT@vMvwX5skC9jVwofB37BW/dB3@4ee9og96vEI/nd90DuHB@N7cB9nhKVzz8Ef/cPmveJ8nH9ebQG5f87@G9A2FT8On9fqWjn/Nj/i38wn/Pjr4d9TCv4OP@Hf0Cf8OHPzbt/HvVRP/gjUTCq@srITj8QNQGV2mfcx1DL9UquG@@cwbDoV/oxcLQXOox5M3N6epb4fxctn9Bz2q7L/hxV2Qo/pNMrnybTUeP6WcnVbdLK4kc3uFPfasXuW5pnuq8e0KYI@vnK5UjDX6pRpVuJL1b6unK5MYCEm9@uxZHBvsM0BQrZ@ehsLXWCcVvC2y0/6wUyerQJXkqVTI15PIgefDDrQnG0EygpBeRMdnlPvQkZdCYdSBS1wVLpHHhy/f/2/4O/vy/b8u0cePMCSEHB6NP40/FTXxUpQupItXxt74f29vCAHqUDw3LLEn9qQ2CFUmKsfiSBwNxb6xJ7XBqcCf2AenKnaGYlfURV2SRsMJVHf/9/cM59WeAdgMiOkMRQcRix14dvf2XgG@DqR9Dn@qKIpDyORQvIR/UUMRTxY96fltI3YWOmXCBwUUiJQUSYmRVCESUev5gvlRSEQaZ6eRejmcts/O0ly1YplcmSy53tw0Ghu7641GGpltIf4snnwGV6UaX3EfT8PV8tOz5STWsVfb4fTK07NqNonuQhwqMIN@8a@8xhjhWZ0/C8FY8eQEfydXl1fcRQ50nZ3Q1eDBJydp7nV14l5XcKUv70Aw4WCgpf4D/bf3/sv6f3XMoqf1GHD69Q0MfOmK4V8sdn1zfePeq7Fo1H2JrsAfesA7xrm@qaKTgK7BdRqN1WM3N9wP7tHYCkdYxURWqhR5DAitOcxTPYuUGYNhVdRdkTs7G4pirNwEH39uXv5MizuxMm17WWjighwMJaTFGIHkc@VyznUvFcvlouuWCoVyedGHEuHFdQKQYsutMjJ6OWzGMA@c/aMizsiQuexI1LWt/tQ0YVgolcTPn32vRqOtWo0G@mc/fz6DlhTBXS@VUh58xOLnz9D8IjEYMu4a7nprCQaAUjozRt@TbdlxrOgn1UycRXDToX0WiWF4RhQRGOOz/MpKIVetFnLgLhRjsbKwwLfMRLvxkhS7WUgLvBgwmIuE3SCpuBQj35sIhrPwCntaBRa38WLXN2GiNsvlY9HmSIn5HlKpxH1YrhAtxkvuX2U@xtLVReb@nZ5m47nFpcVn9fpYM0EpUb6WK9JN5VpexgmGm3LLtVWNG8TlJ0@yJSBLUSyfhRqN9dpRrYEfU8LFa5S56EnyJoQLk6YVOaXZoHypfooFqZ9FIsvlZ7xei3kWjpRduGQEJBcrlqi8YRhyqh08GTIErIg3FF6WFjPZ@XR@@E1hQ4Sh0iJep6enxUwxvghybbFUqtfr5LvCY7DFsMmkpWx4MWTSXqMlkbVxudbCKbR58IS6Y01cWbcVTfNsgF8Zlta@UtvKfCi8v1Nb2zhKZFaga8ps1tYSmcPj1bCEr/nxOwVn8f1go7a@dwwR9nc2aocbz7ffbBzvgz9aDIarvy8rA6WhXA0GV/jeUOhaU235/Fw2zYYJ17DDxRxeX37xky@/@O@@/MnPvvzJT778yR/88vs/@An8/hx@P@PPn/2bUh7vv/z@n/7Zl3/xJ@D57@H37@D3l7/8/g9/xH/0/lfw@48Bv79yfwE4/gsBrt/55fc//9Nffv@7fwS/f@7@/uj27/f@cvbvD3589w/j/fzP7of52b@F3//KcXmwP/sX3A@ft@D/BYf73T/68vv/O///a/cPnX/y5ff/Cm/uy//wR3/9H7/81v@ZyRT/@l99@cnPvvz4519@/FtffvzTLz/@x5kvf/ivJDF4@zPgpL//i1/g/8//4u//3S/w/3/5l3//F//j3//O/0yOP@aO//uf/xt@/7vf@snf/fif/d1vfX/H/Sf33r9/hP/3/wA@j8/nY/A8plxf6/P9D8rPr0ONcSrAA2QznGVAr1odKazMQiIT3Rs0mD/4J1/@8LeBD38fIOHtv4c3@OcvEPRTenn7diIsTkPXZPztW1BV37pjgrdBoJ8y9jkNKqD47DMAvKVQfjEfChL9nxAKwJgL5YFNJE4guFeRe//y@3/2p@jvx0Tf3w7iEz3fAOwCAn/2ivhTbHh@MYKwP8Wm@@UXP/ryp//4yy/@@MsvfgfFcTJXStQSSemB@TIAzD8CDgELj4EDQGkFtw7Ms/lQBhzzKzi/E5LiHz5AJcyDC8Yji6F8Ft7C9TqOaKpnp@nqWfqsyq86vKfSVfRJpc/SGJ5Kw3Cmwb6BgSD@nj1bZN8kk/w59gtJVUINeYxDPybBqHGRT9fEcQ4AfsNQrgRvOIETh@43zoPiELQaZ5VKJR4aViCMQOEV4wxZtYjTCTgArQBejMTjJBpF0OjZcJWwQMxK/IA1FitDHjGOHlXCwDBD6HUgSBkhXqysQ4KV4TpDXIg8HvoAzw@VarEyrCK67ygLgCO@CkkCVAVzN6x@B@8VwgnwoeH6d5CVYiUerxbBp0JFpdQSDUpTylPhqOxxRuVGf8Zw/vLpM8a@EaSiwEfIUDPMhcZ7fAz9lCaKnkL4WXzRLQ79e076LWJ8qPYh0Yf78fCn6E3xXQDAm0zirjX4QTUCwDMIHnJUcUoWHnGOASgXd6dxfA9SfuKhONVvnF4gfcjD466VauAF0WFxFhYWwLVSFbLCHoyjmHWxbDuyhYs6pB8uM6FQEtAbNwEpC/s00lpcX4S7BP8b87SRl5NjMbQQwaF2hHlpJONZI2eEKfde0agsi5TzOMGFwmN/rtvTyhwo5TkWC0XpYyExLH1LMU14vrK7q8YQ9O@EICSkAp97j7kD@nfG8nLlOym3FIInvQ/wOyXuFzOgGvCboClsrEjQ6nVyhRouOEGNK4SqVXd1kUmh6uHGEUQ42mNSRkwxUNqvc0uZXD6Xz2QLhfxSRsoVSrlCvpgFqVcQ85mMVMrlSsXS0g1l6RkIjsTyYjO/Uv1Ht67/5h/Numb74hWqvmXDFEvehKrDZDKdoRxXpPxSeVSBfJBXqEoTHXx4MrpO4qbS0BltYrvG/VKQrdB1Etl0Di4WmguxOfCCC9DiugpzF/u398ruqid@woqvfApSHhghFjoDRuDYQuasK4SV9wQkzhOJO/OFsVNE5xGePd2FdKAqdLaDu0wdgx0ZfDfjqtIKrbinJquhEC0VnQJh6yH8zMppPbSS9kNnY1rr8Y/OrlkG6Pg/HGZV1i940LrKz8v5QVsyWrGz@6rTuwPi2OzjKSDF@gfDsNFvQgZxSpgDrMLN0gxjFsASO96/o5Sv/LPsuOZKh9kB/GD7@dZR4Hm0UVvbChXY6t7u@tQj7wLl2c7G5pH/usRDvah5H8W7jZ2d6Vf3geO0eZZfSiRARsINnwm66Jla@NYDkVJ398VdYGToo9IrbKHDcDSeh6YPw8ZKVR52YLippNINhTUqq6fhejGXXyqInwtSSSot7Q76A6QC6w6K23vCsvCUHS/Ply2UfHZLduREbqncGbEC2mYGiZlAYYQb8UoSP1Ci2qEtGAP28UMqaHLMCeHxuzZuxsCxfRM/Mzkw2Z2e8EAvdFpqtwdC8MrwAEJNWWbw@9oL4ivBy7nfw@FpkN@tEG0GOC49qh0mhlI0J5gpFfPFUjZTTBRLQFypkM8npExCWioulcSEJEpFqVDMl6REMVfK5kBcQmi@tBQKg1hRO@k09AaSINBT1Vtov3oFDYEbqV41FOZTKtAFR2Xo62MsLIcbvu@gyIRs8UyEyAJ@jsZ2aL/xoloR8MvmIn43HFDLrMXCm5tr4uamIKziC86BromC0MaXfFEUl1YFQaGQNZDtGUEweBwIAjCHv4ji6pogDDgCPJ4vCD182SigXisIKr6s1TY3MZ1zfMlgfAC74CH8RfNelgBMx5dslhRjQfjoowO4Gk8oRzndwBdME0M2ecgahAnCcy8/oggYDjgcx7DllbVWE4Rt/lKrYcgLKnieZ/UlvtToEgQLXoAbBaELjq6lKLogNMGJPCkILXC1RjL4odVwPMmtO7IgjDiBkESCMCRouXUhgMbl@mMyW1tbcs9pK11@jSz@bEHWIEQdDjY2m8@fN7vdpjWqbTw/wJAXL7bk89HAanabbrRmAy4D4kDIRX80fUEetxsNWZsZ8hJC9KmQxqihYN4a8kfIk3t1MZF@4wWEvICQ4YyLY4OrD6BNvFb78FyVmxTiXRRCz2GzKZSRUZ2RqeAkFDYe2raV6Mstyyjj@7AyH4lGEqPTTL1MvqwfjV2L5RsM7ETp41goKWPXo9NhRayDEi6VcS4sOt9/KoDcE5bn5afRIboLIM6kTE6ILc8vDqNniUbsqZABNXgZvzJmdCIskpSeDopCYUlYXoSn8FTIgnMYFSMiY3BLxE6X6k@FJUQqPH2aFE4lfAUYOZnDFMAlLJWEWPkGSOFAX9UcOEqjEY1eKfJFLIa5RaWCso3T67Frvk1tRGVVy53oMDGs8OywUayMhbEUZwB9lXgLZxtPsA/wqzwccxcIM3wqLlPpITNFzEc6HVtB8YQCBZ4f3Fl@f7r/5GSGk18ptpzkn/CSioVYCrfAN4xOg76Uwj4EIVGTPMGTKnRK1dvSREq0vRw6QnWTvqzM0DZGEz@aRweDYRzDjfQwPuqXlkqhUNXVv/Bse2oTP7ppWCn8jJ9TDobwI9me15EydFJbCu5Fanl@a/yIaGpjiB8VVg3dCzgcgUbRT23vpY51W@4o5evkSfKGzivjYVM86a@2mVypgktuRyltJseuqBiNarXSqPSVvumMYARDSnTVjwu9J1tlHBKPrXg796GjhdKJZR3t2lC/uzAMD0PVNh7gX62sXg@WlwH2pqxU6GOiQlgod57qlQFlcF@x8JDJ9h705Qqe5mj1PpxtINwaEPL6Jlm1GJTOy8S2zYnjnxug/FxjftyARkW8KXcrp@j/GW8rSUGoJ5Onn@ugWlfE8igsV@xBk3/9SWyC7l8oD8FPWsqVNSANP9mzQPv75HKPNSvNb4dlq2IOLKVM4J816BcbqQa0x9NMJpPIiKVERoLeD3pFCIbfErzn4CfBD8Klpfr8fFSLCowJCXEopqSEpEgJx9jQgaji8jLSFiqFXuEpx@KZRS3aNpi8kqQ6gsZYxgyAQOgxU030ohDrQJE1Dh6Lf3xaSLJcnsXKH4EE1kK0nVqNPc2V29FV1oiBB3Th8MuwQq4crNJorNypsOi3sXJ0PlaxlY98kEFFNOeBmHy4sWAP@qfifEFKXCcbyRtNtp0FaSmzfDpYOE1KUDrxc3dFeF8V6kDqmxCMTIIz/qAdlMHPa6hcnxhrBGM/swwKoKZAxUilTNkFCZmu1AD6RfEbl3y/WzQSWcpEIrFIGaDmwZukT@yaREQEJFjkiQRyC/rqZaGUgfCxsLmVAz6kKkih8E2ordomy5VC4evQzfXNSjWger5ko5EcT3qvTxjrxmF8naZVylQjzObJlUxVaXKhVql1D2plF7q2RgPhdGBnATvjpyqT6fmvXRiNr1S/5c8zXC@HNEEXbRraKau7q7eZbChsX4c4CWnTQXolXk2fhQQBm6C7zBUt5mPuAP27MJkZZmvX3veAl1/hKJFF5WXeuE7rse92Ve26mE1W@R4/Fv4Oio/baarp78LATDc3RFZ3M0sorBvevhYYITogykB65/MCDucVZh6Wvl36tvjtq@O9471N9kxcLi4XOW3OniUSUkSKrLBnoECqBxuQyc/MyEvf6S/K4WUzks1FssFhwVklPKzk/GJJ1WpSWsmwp8B8bBnERUcqJMXPVc5JVQooZCDky2//UW64UoT3DGhly0xaWcksZqrkkcmDRyazFAt/@f5f4wnpzJLnkgpL4XqYp5UDgDrfl5qRwtW06y0tSbGwneRvkI182C59DmfEYihcfPXhM2MrMOqotrtdNUOutMcaC9f8Yte3r3j6tt/Nyg38V29OV1ZuaLrjxnXg7eaGB0/802N83QEzDq9/2/i2sfxdcoX/r8Btfm2PF1Mo5AUWC38AOWTbuNBWCuNMVgRGaBEGFGSmEgfxC/3Xqc@aUvmmXDdN81vThEHGok5/ir2If@P3Rdu2Vxb9VwUDWb4qMRiUpNNffvsPM5nC//Mffu8s9hqkcKlUKkiZ8K9uX@nFuRBbnKuxCLccyLtwtBDsn@aLTHyzE@euFueS64d7ay83jrAPV3T8lj1b29tNYRB@bn18HLOlKbKljdzvrY8QCrv@o7V9ZljseH2f4pzQQVzypSkqN5WF7fay@2W0xCWTUllc8s2nxVxayjOpuCwuLWcKTAaZaKPhDde1gFEZFWvNMEd8MBldi1HkuRrCYNiOCsN9W1lmz/d3KAYJncW59Y1Xe2xvd@ddyvPl/kdb24fscG/z6KR2sAHleLVxyITaIds@FNjJ9tHW3vERq@2@YxB8UNs92t44RATpEMpTVHI5wfyRHVuxR3YaNWCbhncT3rbRulCcSX/ZMuU0mrye9NbxI1gKfkFm0n@gqzB2DI4cD2tzXG9kiF5ut60QngBWW2wOx4pzi6CB4AHknmgvsfzg7SfRys@zVm43ssRa4q6eXVlimuj@MS3Xzx6w@fn5M13wO6NgMfyBa9ALz46A3zhP2@835qKFHFuEQWomFxuH7O7tz4ne29zJwdGc5IcdrM9l/Jftzbms/7IBbzn/bfNkfS7vv63WXs4VxtF21@aW/Lf1jbW5ov8GTDpXGuPcXZ@TxJBHrEtQEufoq7DRze2dDbYIQLHyRChOHKJjyhsIEQXFjptjQZKzxcWrnpGg8U9zNAXdVh6C9sAnoOZQtTxFutYTbNEw4QZKKwBDtJA/BpGtbivhYkWjcdB5ha5Dc1igOSwQwM@hIQCEY/MVluGfve/w3SdRbkQ0wYRjm477fmOzFRweVIEZEmSFjo59QwzF/Tx0aO7GRRnt0ORqh/ayE6gEORUsIRbDs6K7xzs7PDGTNOKoQJCMq8czcBomYIMiwh2LDr68cni1UF0greZcDQc/YR26majN0HRtIimgnHNzLUAwSd1LWUsw1PASuOMB8eILP4MCwBAMbhFc/JBsNNrCsnYVp0UZiiExN/Y2eQlxz0SFTdZyjGGiRCkK5qdbPn9m3tuZM/lqTb7qEY7bRc6zxfHxnFYQNoZ@c97pZIIgSwwUcw45Jh6H2FAcCguUaw6IDj9uuMHLZRUSEiPsyRPKxwq8lSKUBMaLU4osiSCIwCUYkQ@R@Vmbp@zG5tKLuG2JNjGRoWPsR7gF6ubINzoDknU6o1O16rdCvzrndBg5l6cEshvUaWNdgzubacA7ikfg5ARrQjNJMC9QKmAgjiYTTEmwDnhPydSGqgPnKtZYJnqsAI2Ran93ndcQt7BE/tyDSgxyb5kqDITFE2y@xOhzc01LkS/KHhTIQ4ICvkWmiSIhONz98Q7WKdoiby/Ilhj7MTG3N5c9PuKxgR1cTiOyolEMzituccmzOga6hd9Fhu23Aug5S3Jk8bgL4XOZC7YxCZdMcrgbjy8fKMTGdCnmv7oUKJbvLMXGI4vx65UCurUxi0ApQMRHAW8coOk2WZuZWSigLyQUVJofhgI60DEvQRufQPCI@NDljuMnvz4@dNLL000Z2i3UIJcKPMrka2vytT35is0XfGS2ssIyORhRNdElFcCFxhFYERxtLisnI3YmX2myqcIUL07Hl8A8BeA5FJUcDBnwtjBGCZKy8cM5ch8/31Zhtc3G9u7G0WQo4kvZDTfjPcfQNUojNgnmZgjD7Si@xPwcRTtIBK5vRvd5GgmiZ@Pw6GCj9ioB@YuxlXELmNYB4Oa2hIkS3HgpgK@utKA/bidY9LDGFmPsCeYswdyJC3x5dBKaYSuA6s4U2wMzQ0mJHMR/n2xJYWyRoRlJCVEWjbHPZ2fQpYpLTOqbn7P9rL6UbbNRdgmVXY7H10FcKe8JmF3eNLmygZBtbjB1eWZi56LIclaWOUoPNO6haN3GT@W6wb6NukXvCLdp0KDMLjM8MY@yxTV4A/3ipGpzvxZJfSPyAfpiMwY/7M5pgjJO@jmyJ4V6ChbPS1v52rw8pNFO5iXJ87JCid7Ow6/cSV0YLoWmjumT3SDDdEwZT7K7gXs0FbyPXlYoxCdzAubjogZ@MsuJLZPZH5QpjQZaSm40oraidYBZjYHVgi4f1WXbBcMLQ1M8kBoSOiYDXfKg/jQZ0Fbx5DnaoYVeZwohGnYBbzRWGaUUQyE/Z7ajmJSrQDZwzg4/Jx9MEAbYE@9QrXgiNJDj2LKrFW/K2B48ZKcTFr84joHdS8zwBvF829dn0xlhPtvMCEPDjrOieJYKZoSdD/qzcgCC4Y4Q96zxjBDd2JsVgRvMGgfUTwMEPA0SuF6PxmZXPbSryRoPWDwj@h9ZA8U137W9F2BBUC5dDgzUdXhdAaZtqfhNkmlEvrUDiBkdxgKGF3y2io05SbZbqjqN3sPkIqKTw/TZDTZcbvUA6zdSphhLBBAGMLa5Xea7cLIAUsjhDCRhdki8702z2j5qZMFpvOP4KbQbordheDeOYJj3wGPoGBYr3wOeQ5NvfojPzDOa3Bjd8m3GIX9cAMDqlyaM490F7RVCigUJ@usmn/za5JOB9LFN/qCkK@x0Mh/1eOB9GTzGZfQa@A9KyMv1ZGqxrypxkGsU5eIO9kUjRoFkuPGSyWR9NK4E8nnKKwqhR49HCgnEFUT0FfKFqs81rTAr9rj/WaywpOTH4RJv3BpoXjqQ@RCaXWk00F5xo0GGKhsNnFlqNASeAnW82OEFO123sfGwFGipDYNCo0JSFhJCMlk7XNveTqq6kOCfeagItmNYSgPtzQkJXPSuCCSwGgjTUzSzIrj7FWWbUWzh7jRqgTSggA8nQkA8lW2dEhkbIn44uVawSMYjimRMJTY2jvqI1A4oNbQDcV9KFrcy6CW0Robw0LKgpagoaPgHLJAfjA5ZjJkwVIJT@m4WeLo2zfTZaB6GZ4keDfRz6xrtrOyoNKqm2T7BM5wk3LJz5LZ2nOpBBGNO5dwn7NMH7RgZ0Wsrrp5F00MpYWxA1c1Yyi1pgN89BY3bnRl3aJPGlNz8Jry5SRunMaeyOhYshomFPxXQ1hJUwL5hwt23twRu3@ISuNHmEnp5og7caHAJY3Rch2t7CVxkfQmewN7C2NhrXx6q/QFO3AQteria3Dhb2OVjSajXp8BJ6ccpihApDa1mR128sbiwLEDRbbL0NG3tCeFnGXyK1UO3hSyZJ8dsBlSHWUhnmpCKJX4DlRRQxFA0225uIG5CYAJXQiiutFyHwWeAdzwRg@rzlJ/BZz0REZQk4ccf91cBg1GVieEFUgQGDzwz4wh8lin4DVlS7mPLvgoyrrEgFFfcZuQbtxrfmfEgBk9Ri4XuGUn9/2acFKyS/0KHSv/fD4puDX3@gYcy9wxhvnq08hscFvxXhf6/KvQ/QKH/jWnzd6jk0yhvt/gpdf1BNfzr1S@SeSPoNqzuJU69ZX6IHvYbUgSWvkoP8HJ9Kt2nCzzcP3toMsFu/Qf20qFfpY/ahZNNo1arHfUl6@B5rVvr1Q7QNtequBM/Oc@trl@tPl9t19bXuy@6a7vK62Itt2O@fFt897zz6aMC2vvW3ov3nzSz1Qu9PTCvTpT9q6xStGuDwcftrZGztXrcXzvMv1u6Eje0fGdV@biu2euvjt6@PHqeP4xffXyx/@JTX@zb@x1RLvWzW68Kb9ZGJ3oof6ketzd31L3@YXvjONPfWVffbcbXxJ3D0mtJ3Nm4ep9du4rnxfS2@XLv@cHxeXPjvXawvfOuvfbRkAsfL67M7XS71Fk7P3gT2su@lrY@7u11NzKl51vpq/WO2RYzW5qVP397sL96/G6r91Le6G/mj0tvz0f7hd7r15fObrybOykMXtm5uF57/TrzUn9@eblxEGrKxpGVVU6M15J5dbVvlPpLysvdrW7/tSXp6b38m/hh/@hqfWNV@7g0zB6/O3l9lTt8N3j1@sX7PVE9PGxuyAWz2c4cnh/lQq1@djt@ebxxXJSft09e9y@3t/Lv1tOvespurb2vXTzvbr03Dvd3tmtZe6BLO2uX2rvnvfNXF@tr25qxf6HptVw6rx213@3thY5fqM11Zeut/aJ23nuXzq9e5N7F2@bzo/NPvYsXq4fHe8XMcH8kGmv2QXOrM1w/KGSK6Zb28eBTx3glHb@OFy7PX2TUd7VPTij7aZQv7WjvlL7@It7qvh9@1NLxY0lae7/96d27w61Lq1nTjz@@2Tw4t1619T17Tzx48fJVU7soOufme/3wUGqJz5WLV3FRDg2Pt2yoI@VIzi8d9Xdem8N14@PB9nu78Cl@eXKRVdYvDt7UPh6IzSvdfKtbO2p/TWzvybU3hrMxGD5vlS6PL7a0nY979rvQqw0pn980OvZq502u9Db9PN65eP52VTocirv6QSdXsHbfvD5R1Y3e2@NPB6385huz2Hf07utPx/2N@MbOsPdJKYpN7fDdhR46zh8e7Geu9Jdq39ncOnhVcPbEnTf77a2RVHutSFf60toovz60CtmT9bfWu4st3Uy/Uz8O9kXlMt5@Zzq512qz03qjtvovQ4cvese7@2@utvMF63lfV1f3i@LuztbabredeznafjXY2Gmet59vv1XemkeFi8zG6klh/e1h1jm6eOmUWpf97H4xfqT1ne5xPPRi0Bss7Z9YH98M3@dq/aaSPdDeGaMlqb/2wswM39Q29j51L/ZNY1fazIzSxzvGhSZ@Orr6tGUXaqN4cXjs9A3nSBrmpdeh7NUn03lhvnh9uLf6Yu/9Czmnqify@eGbtpg9LqbVnpXdLhSeSxubnf7HfkmRPq2/ysrZfi9u71yk22vt4zcnF9p5/2X/vBUqluzW6vb7gWxsNDOS@G61s5FXdlZ3jiTluPvyMLe@K@6/be8ffxwetdfeDo7f7KnixvmL0k439/bgTenl0vsj@0g@Md6@tHZDw2LWsKVCKX@VPSwV93rWYfbkvOS8f3leWNVOmtKL7Uxf2VStt8VR8cL81LvqXh0qYrP7fP2jfNDZAEl6vC/K@cHF7vAwlH1z1L9cMlfj7y5aL9/qklY8UZfSRx/PSxe93sur9VbupPbpo5x/fq6UDjfTTW0z/zx@sPZ6/7y7fvKpmGuLqztv5LfDjZ7zLvR6S10/L51c7A1H0uvNw1G/Jupa/vLwJH95ZKwenmwdFnuvmlanuXXeA9nQHx2fXw0ut5Sl3vCq@LJ3/kYWd94W13Q7ty@GXijb/fbB0cu3tXgno5Scy713u@ZJ8WSYf1U0TkrGXlF9Wes8H77e62yIS6Z6cjQ83uilV9fUfhFkyr52bK3tvd56f/LCFEMZvbD6ac3IL32MXw7fFU7S@/GdwbvWUaZ/Yllbb1Vr8@3l/tuXh7Xt@HZz9Hz/Qt57t5E/3F1bs1/EN9WCMtrKXtm1tazWMUJ2f3W4O7TMUvb9xU4XegKjXWo/P8qe6Hat1rnaLh5u1GrP7eb2C3k4fN5Zgj4Cr42TN0Yl9CtudzHETS7yh8xNt4T6drdpDEFe8qOPITq7FqKzayF@Wo22a/NNzr9KL4aOgoc08Iieawx/0ARljbUNVB5SbNs3jozfRkmwvgHRVXS1DJOeiNY9jtLGAZ8Gd5qvwsOV9ClXZWhqhoqfncJPYOCY1Bp/dTEV2tNZf4TjTUfp86MjKn45yrVlTF/N4B/oIluqoblWi3kfvE2RpV7/87cfQIEw9W6STDN3WTLZ6mhy1waH1ibXh9Ch/@kATEFTZZz8wCSknYYsiXl3ayp9pBIzd4QfvNp9zvALgLgN1htxyKBMjMiiDU5SkVUbBT@KaauXijaij6wo7VSI7/h81C7IoB/uIJ/0I3uyU3tDQd1QrKkNoCaP6K20phefoVWhZ4tpd4kVlaGGbDVVBz@53uAnOBo8RW/Pmzm595BOPrsLtFwxQs2GLDFzZ18e4ttULKQY7WIfH0DE/XSQIqio3m7DxUWTUNK@K8ZfApgXzbtxq/3ubwr1BO62qkzgNYBWA6AVLUjfWrP/xqZNjj5QOcQX6zfebh813C/x8C2GE6e@7thxGaBy2Xszy7wEgfy7Ob@9LRN3GED2cdqRGzKHol4anJcF2veI2yOhtnGEPd5tmQKuoZ0GiM2k3SinuTrfQSjS1j2P4H6cJ5wTngRy9WRM0Dl3Q4XPA4@MxzdocpDb5UXEHUtRCIB2c3rHVKY2@/2Gee@Ommlqsn6BrjLfKgvjBasVqCz6xkigHDiV5ZfF3T/Jz/tBuSGqvw12nFHB8quFANwNsV41H@vYnGm/PcbhNewnjfNjmIY/6tI0oxUdBy96W2542WJeShx@Kqk9nEns4M5awxrxhHB6JlouAwju0yGZoOjebtVAqStjaiA62tQTyAXwbdnzQjMLyjifCXZ/bnlS88QOtANodlb5ZiCEOvWzVedJ3S0Lgd6xYGEmoo6J420hAmd6kTmGCUTouBwH3RjxCN@deosqfKeXz0WM0@lUrMM/exp8WeYbd7FB4YF@hiIkhs0YR@hTmfMzjaBVv@lgUmPWo4rCHdxYhSrxIlNhhI/@TI3HJ@opgPxURbpJLE7Ujs4IBTHkl8glvUt7gqE9cVAbfCsu6/AdXJzWoSkSrUBCnz/7DQZefW7c986WAkvws6MGs5HBOWfytuwStOy9e43Qd1PImCi@VL25vZeeDtbCANy4MtWhokVBYDbwC0MmAy93y5JpcgdB@NuXwBsrm/Luyqv5@SjEOiW4dLHOnrCotLISXUpGyeubYizmN0Y3eiYQPRAZhHS1yqKZxWjWi5zDyIAyO4kgNxtBhiPILUYlD0HGRSDlAQNXMQjJN6zIuXYScTGA2Mdbn4TB7xTNSH0xE5fqKytF3OMZ8JyKnJmd9cVsPAOROeq5@GQIR8sDAv71yRIB8mwm0I8EUOTiWUDBk45PBoxTnQrwEw2mmavP7Jx@Y8qLd07D63woOn4uVbFOi1he5FS@Kd1k4DYdy/XET9aZ9OG6sR9n6UVkc9ARqElCaj0FD00l@IcL3U4L6Fee6hUDhyMIAsUAEcHDoybY@X19XfPrOzsE7tAEHy9zgkkJVoRhCEgUkBhFiAwihGigdhutvunDQVdcjPEd37wDo0R2ccUZzw9APaHa76VEYoyTD1e4AZ/74TjqQzh9oxChsbO9io83Gwe4Y3Z79zlU4RyWI8HGd6@Y8xyjX8Q1Wecfs1EdFbIAso0PaNyy8qqaTB89vfRdbB5yF34aO49IpUMIxiO72iHxheo0VMPFxknp8ZHiEB3p22o@QDFWhnEGu1KYrCE5Rvyb0EX@CTY69EaxiVTg8CO6GUQKIc2ODmq7h5t7B6@IcvuN2s7@Vg0xwwCzJVttRh8Jwgai64rGO1WfniHsfkFC8zLJTe@LNira4iBY/rVJTjwAbFBIg3ync4Tl5Ux/C557z4pAEsWHBqWi0VbMGbhx76oP5hbGnoGQ1yLPtdsVunma1RNSh3e7J/TkaBUlHdHSUGw94gBj00eTZJ3Lk7SHbxVGmfTFSWq5qEd1iV8s/om9bIa@u418ZA9MXB1W2kKQ/HKrpdhkzGFMfUCpaB1KxJUsAUKBz@zSj@UHP5vi970uDvrsKHW6oq/3jtXcSWURtEdOux@k4wYUJI7F05GuPbWS1CI3Zf4Z8AnVUZ1UGe9KjKd2zlM7h9S4wGXn0wqZWj89n1DEZpFH9chzznVjTzPj6om/lZxqrgON3u6h0SWaC@FShyoMq4ksjBijCVn3xKuyJ14rHrfE2crd/UqZS9hJjcztcMb9pztgbreBbNFbcxt0coVGXwML65@/6MoVvlBPyQ86eUMMgidOaYA67cF54hPPUN3JGYgJpCGdljl1k6tTp@Lji7oIWdLLTyyga9ApTHdWQNVBWowPp7llJVXSsN2BYsATxarbC1ttr5ET5Lgzs9rTB7oQCH35gcPxqQR@jI8nVEQnfbK0QqiRQ8Y6KwVwXTWZhAgxPq9BOg2IWywDZU91ZhejeLsYbuE8nUzlJ2BQ1LluiYsCBP0M4x7w9RIvzyx3oBzeYTiMHAsUTCy7Jyi8E73H@ywrZbOB4797J7usUBifDkZrbiyXEcdHjtGuGyuUQj9onmw8n8D5ERuOW6HIVsgzOHQHXVDRNGjE/NFWsevHvPFh8ZA/RmVfuVrkI1jbFcdu12Cz/sDGKUom4wgdj1ZKQykVmgOhSHPA7tdUvc4bALsD2ZJ1R@FnLFGQuyu7mCBFRB1WsaBcTWgZuG0MJX4frerZA0vhE8Dg0zZatEkScVA8qOlBn3YjJVBhuFQsNAOgOu5B/zmSOS47cNFQ5UzgeXrCoerxBiehKxKoReMkCycjdctIPT714roypK4c7YiUy6Mdibo078PMmAEir8sqRGPuDs25BL7VzdB4fNH9Op3XJH3gseifNTV4u5Phg1NvHO6i4X3M7ZG/Wp8xGUPc1Qr2QUN3ExOhojLVY94ZOJIA3hGoljcPwYHoMaxT90S4@GgUKQjjl7bK58IZyQjSIqiXoi7FQq7DXTquLT8KnvM/TU/8XIHWF3N3BozcA3P@8UgXAlk@xiHcs5HTENg@OcQwiANywRvqYnq8/2CIOPzzbii@iUO8UTi6Y@64ABHwcS2pXTz//Eza7FK4bZQS5UfSpnNKQbFAW54NxovsgmHpAmCQKZJHi755HA52vD8@9@YBUu5pQuq@zE@k9tjMu8ndApqgxCOz7hPixp2rm4UUIveNS4UvUrnbalw1M1A/XEmCSnQZgXiW2r07VeHSwJMKPHfNQAyuM3txPElCIe6h39six4XyHYsZ7ziwJ9D9ac7xud5ZBeWc7BXVKybVIH0eXlNN6hony@o2i2BZk9Ltwi4FCuudMp4orBvJK@dt@w46ODqaccXtL2CHIrgnl4Vv2gn2TRsXQ1yfYB/lUWOW/Js86xxokN9Wxi3SL5@fVzo067/wtuquHaJoD/I7xkO8otfI8fvg1AVICG7oZW9zPY81N@eqM6D0TMTLxNxpZ5@dPRSdDshr2qqP9nt3Mh6mMccQlgr7juOhLuiTYk0Ae2CfSc5jBmI@bEeFkgZgA1zkSuaJRupxBwbE425/VpmYDR4foL6TEYNYXNkZOKJ8b3ySKbdzMcIw3k3OxuFFcbv7cfsvBzMyujMjSA5aI3L7On/NiJtEuPl1V0bHupvpam6gd5kZuH10FTFXf8uLnh4QNcf6gj864OOBoG7gKtqeMogTW6DAw9iYH41OMEj9TvixhZGPfIEPj@ZBTLIAEoxGpiaCAonnMBMYFpmBQcztbFLtEEVNXieT@aaKpIkQHzsvxhPzFJGlM0lcBuTOuHSrVBPoGB1yptm4Mjf@Qaos2l@ncWrQ@gdW/CIWHpcsx@MsEw8He7sdCIXaNzWFn9yRdhq1vW3ftBXrOY65nE4rtoFedsqwuukr9UJNc8DQoWu2KqkMsJ2jkSoe0tg4hq4MDU45KXao8M0KqPeiWvaBhpPKIPYBI6EFLB2AOx3QePWWgp/Eca5w/4CLwE4FMwvBsg16uKGzkWE0x7mX3ZM5PAMJyrsNme8CYQbNFGQg3ZIdWxkpaYyYbmpw68toRTsNQ/I0ljC9pys7EPsQmoSSOpcv5dB6IGN0cnoqVbJ1F0ri3BGFOPg9edo9gnMIDu6LZE0D6sbfn@oOEsgYpqFrI6ajCYAuYLpEaJAqkBRy3hUUk3bcuos6tOVBoXFETiwVSNjbbg9H8bD/TqUgLB8L8W8hL@P5DttAdrEU2ptK0Sf2tEztyeANc3ITBR/nT/q10DjXw/s0/C0e6XQgrqE/Zt/HrD0eZP8LyH7Xzo90GqdHTU0eMeFKJvvlbC23JBaWcayldnViQ2wtaEQnoLErQxO/KIwbA7Af9@JqyqWisSxW4xvVHgDgoTOAIoXCpiV3@7IHGM0uM0wmYKOLxtcTJ/rHQYahTfp08NwEG4@o8WQaY9IYG53gcnsVJKbr7fYLSgykFtye4pZnwzDZMjjaSnPQpc4Az2V5MfB0lJxoYgQ5Vo02Y0/huQxPyDpZxYZ2jI2/4tuvwv1EhspOoZnXmbdAIZRDVApo@hWe@7IXH3sOBAus6ECHzVc1oEdYZA13MMpnCQAa@7Aoh7P5vCctnnsgbWN7D2dtKEG@udgLwSJyY4Kx8p17ShZZYE8JiAS0N4WMSSaw0mlvZiRSw29Dey@rER5Ks0ZR7h5PEfFeb9Enh7d/ocN3n6yQTTBGBkWJnLGyt6teKrMbDxD3gKCGgztLkhFv5wBqmBauzYx3pADpBW8Udh/aQAayD0BSxSGbYb8UKAbf4F3ns12uCjIdLNW9NSzwr4hljxr8U/J@/Y8Xs57w2pyjgs/Th@mvmatOCy2@EEOrJO4C00ResfNyeYS4g@Nyu/go5wfymOQGdzaRJk0T/oQqzyifcwVhgTpnkrqUBBuyLs6@8@FTgo3cV7THH@JGt8XEqCKVfcvcij7oX@NgJMGjDMwEAt8wBaR9OYR3d0Rn8cT91g29BIl1FOQhEhToder549TG/9velzU3kiTpPRO/IgrsbgBFnKyjWSSTXQfZ01zVJRZrumZRbAyOBJldIBKDBIpAs9im1S2TTGarHc1qV3uYjlnJpFdJtqs1kx70PvMf9hfsPxj55x4RGZlIkKzunhmTrGt6qpARHh4RHpd7hB/n9bJqXGxxzV0OECdbPPERi3M/Uxfr9RD4NpskivB/R3JMbH7Yy5elPjwZ8I@G@bF@VI5rEyLaVs/m4ZvirDynrUPBHmlHSx34rS/n@XPuZLGPEv1OozcY3MO22nh3bIF2ReOBTLVmHglIrbmHOzzx/wWGV5YFO5AB/KYiwEoFgCShKsPscj6Tmba@2doa8kmoS@ZPR5uQsk35hXyMHuOX8i7@i9hJHtOhNSu35iWjl0IlWvObTAKrnnKx0F1u3rfo70J7U/1doIft7xJ62P4u0vMb9dfeGL/ijtARw/9AxoHI/glJ1ARtE@We4hOFxHp8Qu3@KF16OkLApVRpjpOxWDocjcII7tmzWyB1ZjSC8510qvMTqWOTfpOAXJPro8ZGnZYeIh5EOVni4xD8YpF/I6KnnF/ETw7kbluf0ZwAzPf4Rt9@VlLfVEFJHyVuktkSbf9Qleypwk4Q2/aG9Ys95VS1ZRvOHRUZTHFh2/uSkk8Hh9N1Vl@k1pgiIFRJZRWZgu9AuXQRpGUX0VTX@2OyFKiuMkuZQURprV1pOCHedvL7IiXFXHfeeWtq8e5M09XhJ6wca@97Z2tmgstg8E1vYc2c0iSK7ff5tu2RKGKr5/p2CmZPxMJPTsbh9PhEwVEUeEDAikp5PwR3D@6SuHqEcZ3CV82mUYsrxt2398c19XKkSMhn@3ms3CfP1SMw/p057pLlLqDoHBNaw2plxfBOK/GV9grv9Bb4SC765MYhrp7HzGnALuYDNeEJbuKo@gOeThkVm0Os0rAcSL49mSA2ADjrQLqA7sfFRniGiQuCAzA@vphZWbGg2Y2Vaey0llvnNvcxTZWs1tYzG8lmqOlGdnxc9dUvaZzcIqbvbqg5qB2t2fV/DeNna5XXa5L7r5iaVKmZlWWG80nIhXI0MTswzTtFdGJ41pCZShI4oXwajiEbzsuZmM9wH8erq31GsheLyoBbq@rmnJA8@xaKRpml@cXtpE1DxaYDQEQtYNZK3s7wXobgdij9hMVRW1gE4IhZOfidlWaEXbwym8KLlBiHXd/vRWBZ25gr3M4izBv0cjWvhL2gfQwJkSR1s/Wa5vB9NEuLJ0FXrDIePUdTxv5PpsFYhG20pkpjyXo/NBUenfjdNwyLEE4x9kowrBDZhpNK2FfRT6btMa4cwrFaK0Q5vcfLSXOgNXHSfJTeoLYSwDzzvEUmxAEG@wlXkKlpZe7rcFVj9jxW1kFEkUKk43noOyPQ1r37wa1JVdF@ZS9k6HgeaAvdIGI8jvhdVv3pAHtxOKoiDzthsrPuFxjLzg1PnBgmuul8JIBkY03mOhi1GsrYYijyMa5PYtlprga/twCNqpYAVwTaylgOfS3RiJQJuiWed9goKL6/oGy@Py9ivkUGpg9di7GvRQiUqZfKXMkiWj6KF7EOw2HFxSxgi4gJDmCl646f9xsaPwUGaIi9hzYYmL/jhrHbxmUlN11Ln7TSuZeYyLortA@cTgeT9tAPp9Fg/uueCLkVjlmqeWdKmvPnj/Rnkh2HGCbSWQ3BANR@7Rmru0E3AYI6bd7rjzeRkz/UWw0G7jTU56waaDOYqGziDuGZqHiIvMc6D4ej0QlI5cBlAm56oCYwYRuvsqgN0NbJ5mLDSZXLGQW7dncy5U30JIRyBXRKp7gPgo7HGCZiPCTYsNEXIA9H/lgqo9k2D6fKnM80X2NXn7RBxr42A6pUH32MH3szuoV5LwcJ4QFuBxVUDo99pwxtv9RwAue7I2q3Od46vr6jwOEmr1uISIoauFr6F7gDsYGLK/zGtckrHO58USVwp8rV4VaAFptzSyZ69sUbWr4vGUE/pf/ELLO56zKwMqG0bj9eElirYvFazgiwwRYrWhQDD5oa27CwoHVJoM3g6IaHtxbR2uC7M4ziGU0Qvz3unlCXaLwCTJjJmOnUC3pMNpLhcO1tXZlHitAjslJJGOjh9LQDlzR9ppc10@R3D1ySE0gxRl3immPTy4B3uGCN5vNrqHry/XGvZNeWVMVyCYQfArT3SDhBdZv4/lITBt@xZpOlTr@oP3EVsg6y4LupE@GmRPujX8haPzKe663It76Vxti4BGMpvjxLmYThwmviqDidheM38nKEazfe@SftgO@98RYoCssoZG708MgfxXnykmEu5@KwJryecbCctCdXX/Ka2TShTXEgBj1iOBUTWN7wtmKlZauNXJe5RVtYV26gajoLmlFSVl4uZWO3k8e8ucodotgG1V3TLU1rz10KMtb6KlPs2saDvuauEnNDQ@oZAWjTcly/6ytJU0eF0TCUNF5kHG78mmfAtrS5U8VNuYD4L@005NNzxR/u1M1qlPnheTI74jqsknDXUdW9acwbRJ8sQX6OHuzZAA7fjG68Y8h16paaaf0utrSaiYbXSkr@VtLjJljSlZX5@1CHaWHVxOM7@TzPZr0MWO6wyoDrMjdSUp7ZGPuy9DNMVbSSp4Q7oONdIZiCNt@gT/cyPJqU7HO9XqDRpBpNeO44J31Fdh@a31nrrj2IQu3KjA9WKRTxe@H7vcSYFSjV63XXmfbRFLz0U5nYQGXROuVG3245rJorD/5CKQZnvcMpcMj6LznagsahvlitEBSbrOgXfl2wae7EgV6rUff1HZn0QN1s6Wp1H4wLI3SCH7wddzYsVf1g7B/TPwcBWtSLCuCX7Mt3Nbcrl4nPn@0/Pdw7aB3s/XDv4MUel2RFfmtQPB3V@KYsOoNz76HGW4gSDnFyn48DOsdx4nCcJUjgL7rhZKI@JXHXJ3H8TZtKtqd@bumb@/rj5XkvI3@8KeUPhZln43vWNI4CmAhNoapE/TsTAVyeh4tRSSY/nYHskAparwN4MpC4UDnsmbSZSw72T6ykTsjREhlCWzbgSAn7kzNwgFqaSL4x00kz6NFq9qtax9ZA48oh9pdgHSKAAaB8aN3Oqxyp3V2rRHifeE6wkWirRFgm2ftRXT2Xane5WrUr/QIP2R6Ew@Oc9p7gtIA5Nzq0yogDv2lIzEZBVAX0FuApEJSWHkmHapAPao1qvfbduTSIH7F/S94KvoFJ/je0816008@Mn5Rltm9iADg8zkXKhi4RNinTgi47WlPSoC5V0bqu6JuZky@3Jtfob/2WLciXGJDr1t3@zRiNf7f23Nc2s/7WPhZ@82Y4mRM4YZVjpm@miunFd2ew8/@K1cj7mYtcZUXxvelEtumEDqj2PsYThZsF1j4G57H/TC7scdVkr38io92twxmleDKzayUUbW0Em6TSfByPRmsiX0@JPqFBn1Ar/7Wpwy/va4YtQNzdbLXj9@i1YxyR6Gj9vTThbaCeK1TcXW39i0T7Tb2u2j5U2sdz8J7xRRrWnG5uUkWad5t371RCDVwsXUTHl6e/1jC35i3GqbxzGWeU0fXZYe7MpGRK/V0uBTNK2yBvEx0jS8JrJUPM6dnq2iRquPpWQiFey1Elg@tikX4ptfWYgvFlKTsRcy/xdVuLN0EbBKLiswG2B6X0GCVQxpexy1Amh8aMxbLK9EJbsAmxL/D/v1hb2SkoBh7fG1n9Fo2svrca@d5q5HurkcusRlZv1KbRuNYJhjVizQaqckbcf26VFtTuM/X5Zw8O1eFne@rTl4/@jvrRs5fq8wdPKeWZev7y4eP9R4r@v/f0xZ7iAvbPD/0xVO4VDf2u3/X5dn69Xr@tGPNCgPLb6kX7VH0Wdv23NHm2o/bp/RP5qA79yY6U2nvrj@ehPAeNoMwy0VYTfFckb03mxgkW1x2ayad4RzS@PNFG9uYZyc0S215wOHRrwC1ve8yDsB4XPytZow2CDymV0LTlSZZ1p/G0zkxLr6o04eyf96YgMYVPXqgHT3cR6XN3/3D/2dMX6tNnB/T5/Edws6N29@E25uFLZDHgk2e7@5/uP3rACdKAelXhbo0N1i9rQhXgTJXum/4U4cEGkAr1V8Kr92ouNwyNVUSkCtNh7L6nR1MK7@7i7HSLXbQXP3hw8IMfgqvxf6LyeQS5dByqawuED@owGqHadBTtLXGmDtay0pAN6XSuPkD2Vo7vgPh3WRnkJX4nDnyVf4RrRDxIc9xsYdgMaqroBuEGKuMI1lMcgaFQKG8zyh2qjW8PTG24WO2bDxS9rx2zQo5cNV5aI0aK4Iz7w66E0TUJNO9Fq5urnYwFABdCOkEAcAeDhEn7jb@PSxJ1R0NMJxD8KeGuJHx5Ovr0DFwjDFx1wkMJBLKh2yTjxkOKAEftYCjjmDBrkt2BY6RwkYjh4SRnMDBXrqwSR/y/fmPDqyxB5mkX7NPKNkJF/OxGs4H29pN2fxKpolfCbTCJIP4wEE2t40GbxD2@Fx7DYOkt1Ai42g0Pf3aMo3rDcHIgTiPCdOYq2Q5bblcf/P51y1HJhws1Qm@POw2FKR3/6coGPFxowDdBQ4gq7n4Bt0KjCTO2jCbs66lcjEKakSTyqa@TUY3C3rTrJwpoWaf4ZfDVVyVN5HJcxFHx4dZZDTuEesBDyBl8ULGbCxJiWFPyBK9RMobFZA/it@FTKEOM0cAfG@Lq2lzhwdSoNXF0peDnl9TaabMx3JW18owX3WC7fY2szyh@/o7ELI@fSToQk600F8GfM5QY4NlpDDcvfQXFovmEWyLBHXLx3vG1imrNLza8nd2Hrytf/7h8VKsdy7bQ7snjhSglyjMLi@S0PKzuJGsDmpWmkeaiaQeljT6j7JZY5QYZMS4nATHf91tbNk@uVRfThxwvK5nOie/eeVKqwvYmPIUQSSbe3cqqaaosc5kjVdII4r2TGgvPuialzDjtfn0fce0xCltEkSH2EVavccOqsX6N4@0aD3q0s@Q0nybDbfGXTCxyPaP4T9Edj9oXxYfe2k6pZqB4MVlyFs0WXTaYGyXdqwsML59XC@h2L0dH@/f10W1c2jo5Ht4L2@6l2N6rbZW15bjkWHJwXR/t15eglcPtG6GlvpeXI5ZDchGbnel2cpY/WDVz/ooaf7wwdrz2CA3OXkRUtUid2qbDATzEFeVSnJrGBUoumpghenG4u3dwoPJ7uGXbpLK077WHXbYvxTYI3DeMpyOxQ@bNrmqZJhsmyDJPJuVCzEuT1V62mDOJt2Sr0DxIWdPDbhY2ai9JJjNtHSEnC7MQMLyWDdFQLtm6c7MHRU2N@KIJTSgVD5rTwVxmN1fl8BEn@7zJxHQrC28cvQlGlpnxZ9pZF19Vj@cuIsMI4zhoH@PlO3v8Phf@eNPUIwyW/5MpdxhK@F34y1cvqOIRXoqryRG8ZFjMkLLOCs/SVUM7NstLctjffkLZWOwXmhd2tnXNHOumCX/8gRPJjvnT@3jnn@vM7qm@7zRbPKdsuwNaig@9YvIIIiaTxGB1350VVPzoQh9hTA17TnqWIXfX2gfcmqZpJUcz07i3lgN9SBz8nbvp7SFdFe22l1ZV@W6qklMiUZMTd2uxBpNJmO/euXPrKtzpXpjilW@LW86Q9P45OR29bTsoo3nEqkI0c/eflk1@PAEuIZ1HUmCvaBZMqiCxOhlnSqLvfBi57aO2nI1hi0eNefbysIz7onStJTVLtS0bu5xILnYGWeiDs4RtR2XVLFD/4vLqHnJQtyvqu/H@9cliAxDuwy9@JWEyD8IRtkpixMct8YpKIvlmBK24CUpI8EHr6deJgXnfxLFsSry5@/LCDRtpqfH@JHwDvX4TOVPHNsvjGap62h6dv8MF1zu@MpU82AToskFZ3f9SdFQksub9XshKBH0byvK@tDKZRtv825YbfHMT6oOcJwDOA6ZnCVj4qKBI7tnErYIJNVlYkzTiT2xSRZJork4ge9j0m5IOu4RgNJjb9Jqk93wEnrOp2xrLWdtGvCzsaMh0hMxCXgPzXW3Qn7eY7Db7E8kmNsYmfagbQ7LlILSpNyQVOlUmqanLTuOkI0kiScomrWooHEzBxJ1Lke@/afEg62hzhLBQVsNgcFTV@lOfFLXsWNImHBMZSCrvD3s5HhSOeWpRmSPhPlzL6inUvB8cVVmBUm9AkMnigZWFdD@IC7jAlO6EvpRJJcW4AfhbN0I31Z28qLl5/0vM8LEfdae@2ptBxjexEc2sZMcgq2rv6a569qk6ePZ8L4kaLW6BR@FSRmGPQzHrhnF3zJIt04CH08lJSxLNZzr3zJdcg0K@LdAwHDtA8pnONRUwiiMsS3X@rvdONenwHtlBKfZKR3rQTY9tH6rdcDqcnL@bvePhnRGnV6Up8Im6qOKS4JMFsuiVqDlsMx34LQ5hIcFXtoxbhbgWTuFaZto3R6gtrlNrvnShseXs/klDRyuTN@k4ICdtk9gJQrA8mzq@JZGjexIH3OS3bE8Vi@mG4VCqVheS19THNnCj70bcTVZ2zUrWllVyL65EZpjFU40QRzSuraR6oXoXvDOVxYcKjv6NtLRjqQ3fzXoYnSOGl10Cpn7kZMurhNPnXi75a2HB6RFUyXij@nVDFgSCvMe7uSdzPAHG83sBzG4OBkwW0AIcr4IEoCyTBUAuv4ixld3KeOllFMlucbweF5uzpJYYXUaR7FriRieHIl7rqdHohsSdSUAS/GiRIOicr5kjR9NmoeJli1WlC@qpyOJMS@osyj@ljDrMNi0QNB@PzM/GkZjeqIJb7FL4JEXcFujOOwTBHsTuVHCsuemNdLp7JKkdp3gawmlUCphwpk6qq8dCPIkkks5gqSXLio22dDRw8Fr6aKQt58gB5Sm0BLSSBJVVE8MSKECYi8PJ4oDKSkyCrmWDOpOf4V2sqbY6q9GCrmWDOutjAWslC2sSdC0NurCv8UaZpL1laG8WLx@80hI@1kXnVOXP/O50IieNcVpBa2hCy8NltDR0LzgOJp@omNHiX1VqDybt7Q3tEdukkYB/52PL@nABw2q7TdDVxgixWzi8VJBRsVxHuexbzJhb5jEBLyGu8T7ugDYZwh0GJR6YdEMMk6EFGnOKGVbMJY2Umk3UFhsjqbxaPafPC3C/zdVzEXck8nu@nC9d5KVZW4ldlPpkkrV8tL1taFGdhK1AZf7Z0o1nHOFIJXFU46RL/iRwTCc2FVcc5UHYlcvOMnBtGWGtSekQwPlhJ4UDrymLfTEFCc3R1e3Ag8oiDjRhTV3WKReHEaoWcdy8Ng4jsC3iqFy/HSxPZfXlw2vjEEEwC0ft2jgwAxdpml89JwQX8nc@a6ol6AGzKJ3aLneSU8PibCe@Oum@GFFVwV6QMSTgZ6mvrHZoxtyd6wNHDLoWPSB0LNKjGMhK2qGjmHfuulwwN1CytLBeRLjlVLmBdVbelvogmvToIKj2B3Z9Zyz@lIieuiTRCPneA0JMtXsyJhEJo1nV0odhQBgntb/VgmpWq8U3Q88Pnv3g4MGT1tMHTyBErcoehesbaMuwuk69uo549nLb0mKdIk9B1QLdyPE@7ORx@zSaPT5FOHIsSq2eO3AXeWGgUJPH90XVoX@mPqUsDlq/gBOQVXs3Q8NT5DbYTT1feZsvxZDuCWZ6peW1HWoJw8g80S1hGCc55whbUv71UDRUXg9fTwSwo5pikxkdue19DcMlp6BSlbevJz/0xx3oklSs01IZRajgQ3Zj51RQudA36DEGZwB/Vauph8YprrZfaw@6cHk77bPj29Ng0D7t9NrV0cko14887Z6mWOhHcHKZgzLV/uHewYvWc8Tp2nvElhP4s8V5h/tP9p69PETOC8q6pZP3Dg6eHbRYQf3g5fNDeAxNJeVdQI0lBtMJCaCnzz578NiBke@8bqQYhEQkb9I/2pVPWQWj1oz/nrOZR1lUIVochIfNVFCU08pqEpz64dQEb4P/CXPAl2F5gkcZqstENWaHNEVcf@q82NfphQPF7RhPRxMGZQ34YooSpWQJgTmNjlGAfRFFxLezNn1VbpSRB0O@cFRMlYWBDIrltH1XP@LVgWXyYj7sFg067cizfO4PCRKvTYXppF/ZKFyU4FVyxEpD6cKFGp0cNXaOWsguqSmotdJzThAj99p1K2cM3gmKLUp4EGLLFC4gL4hbam0tKJ3n3ABROot2VYkfda4cG/okjI5fs@KMkbg1FT1fqh8TxP7SFjh2jsjnc/dRiieYfp9iY44mLM8tzfhf01m5YS7a0Sny@1Rs112F9sgjavCDSVEcvbDPvnje6ecu3YAWMtIjnswj9PptTHeYK5Q5Hk22iFCT8VyJBWE0seSinh/h75l27dqFAk2RJlzJhc3nJVfcUcJIKJoIAIt5@Z38ZuzGRswSrOKwQGy7EI0siC9ciPUsiLcuxK0siF/8VECCfnFtzQzejlq/c0e0mRPjmVH8v9nilYqB3Taq0HFhwucWN6exINkTHBp6zYM5qHtmE3K3ZXcvbVkS9S/@O@F2celSFa5EGn5Jsy/B/Mu/n9@UG7prUOnfSA@dDQrMiX7yEhNm3Bc@0lPcNEnbkqax/eUl2PJ5M4rZZf8onhFfLJk0v/irBEz2tPmZGXdl6WdeuFbiso3YqiGN4H8sIvDeB0FLypv1xd5GxYAX2eubFovpQYxAQG65IOtpkKwq311aZd3F18issuGC1K9T5S/@Wtepz68MiD@zELzXamJmgv6vxEJj1XwqlAUaCSRsap7Hr75LwY@TbXCLZYE/j7FzkaPL2/3L30u3Oy6ZCf8PMicnF3Dnlxn2TML/h@viuLUUx48FRaWylG4FgVhbWwrxi5/H7RDyppfZZYvkl//o6tL15aX/Xlw6PuZ3zMEtXINBlt4CrXpQMpOLNi02GT8igE3JaI1zjNo15yw5nMXaYCzZgYbN1hZnyex1kz3PzL5ls1PIL4TBMlwS/OsxY7QtEQaZNYp/s5WvMFwmc8dzubaSdMjldoVZ1wbmRBvL42hTHIfp2UkJHDcTQsYiap1b0szeRY654K1M4Sdqj9snwzYCtEbhsKojgARhbe80/DLAQTWuwc1F9ctomTT0bVhrRsBynAfx9QEUKqip2qmI6H6L3A7Adrc7PZ0O8IbmabkKjpFqNbiMY0FwOD2NNE6cuA@nwYB64IFTi1lEEvNG1Eo@hYmVvlb1qaqzql2sslYTvfEqu6HjJG5bdxyMJlyZtygLwOUTM6hURbDtwBoWHgbq54xIXNF6uj@Pg6FfdOARxTUoOwnsF2HNk1JbPDPSNHFwlKEB8nR6msBwrkecdWM8yalGsPgp1svroJyPeaPGPiKEWOuIIFLr2gcdu5YBEm1BNE5iWS/fLgmVGNFzmp6nSYjb5fU6Khohi10UsWdoq1ne7rPbIjZqZRyMzULzKBBHGKPXdN2pU@8ow7bLy//tn//03@VL57WaSeOYOsGwTTIDRySJseLzMHxuvh30kE@0rWIK97@PcQvqnt8NTtuIUDNxUNPkWoKZBhCYz2miwWlVOKD9JjwuOr5gTIWYWLXag91ddfjZwbPPYQ0llwg8C1LFMQk2VX5NyM4lE/laMRggeiYswjzRFQPINGIRyvYKYLbH7F6nX3Q0sIhav/9PmFp8lx9C013WZQohsvPi1Af3hNCtddHagTAzGOPw@/9YMIcj0Z7NRhyO8npi0s@RT5PfXEUWF/olENn1/c2f/HOuTluUEM@He5VTt@plTD/nNvWFLM/ZSuNoaa8S1TARliK@kkR/8BeMLJIg3WYjzK24u6JFkt3tP/vXinHg8YFGzympEnjWrkT0M0FkXw@YckvxVa7E94eCrxfwK4CLqDNPdvEJnZPVMYyGik5y7Qry/c2f6BYTfDDBm8klddxMNDeXORj/1R1ZLquHY9n4OviXjvCfuki1mesyjHJQZeL56V/Hy9TtprhOlvm94qzOVNMyO/zT/5k1@1jHnFYPPIALWneoMtfKkjb/y39l8c9yK7MrJszf/vkf/zzu42xpz2ZL@/PH8WqaLfZitqztK6kt6RWOjPzabOlQ/FWymsTKnXnO5zIEf7mM7rMksWfLljxNfbvoZ1cs@2VIfmaQ2AU/u3LJL8P1hwZX5mJPd2vJcp8tXeYG@5KFnsJ/c0kzaTH@F3cxzi4b@aVrfvm0@LeMHAwfjEcXhqVW0xxOnVnbbdXgf@GZF//upFvj7n64aosZF484KkIHqSkx9wA123ZX/nk6pvyF8DVxakM7WzA9cmpp6FpINGkPooyqPO87q2sdpCNxL6OWnW9WSe6iVhv6YnQ/HfUgdfD73SlLHmN@/kPwgOyd8fd4LInbJnFFrG3YPUGTm3zELzjRwvQBOvY5ZEQNeIDukbjB/27b7lYaksLyxkoayyAUlmiFr9MhCi0VRLQksdY4yhQqRE7NXAj/ye5AIl11RLoCsXQf2Y9snHPl5v0HP7c7kqVSmMSeQrl2Nc7/qIeBVYz4rZw9dmiebjlqL/FlBalkqjkClh7d/9ndLVLVLeclHbBlmP/on9qDzo@gy9qj/sDklT3@IzgmCLP0BHT2T/nJCIqlm/GWsbTmf2YGPpIdalnlOMmuUc@Sav7iH@YxtbOJJNlbVwtZGuNSGUvtP1UvX@wdqGcvD5@/PMSFjOsY0crgywU9EbtlX2YBNnlJsCDLbpGYvy7irJMn0ysoB2vrJe7@v/hjdF/Qrnn5et4h06Xl/jRRrmHKXUIjHoprU0jTZ6G8XFpQ66Ru3VvP29AUIgF6fzjBeo18@qHB5GJCHD7rs02mv5hMu1K3rljwXGPov8tuOZcxyy8TcNRhALyGwvh59e9nxm9mZvCV1Ryvd17Wa57gp14Yl58M@pueQYmbzewL37Ozs2of4amm46DqR3BPFMExXG10TMzCMORLTbjNpokXdEm2hfPCafdN/KvSbQ/ftiMoyHwyg0q0d@@jufybW3ZHPDo@lVAc3/SeWCm@7S3Py90yISt3um/K/bPels4Qw2CrcCKJ4H7G5uM0Mr@CUd9ChBPcs9uszuBNNxwwt5vvDOggy8dVSw8N5Nx86u9RIIYx5hJ5rr2fKmaai6JIofBowDn0k7gqY10czJrzo0TxmS2e0GaJJCLmpUhFIRj5osfBYQNmkj@LKzXVNmfaWbw1IcPrA5RCDCTQzA1MwiIcOTNRit/BCxXSADlPpMHyp@txaUNv@aJx9MzEoDkxIoL7xVrzi9fN10fDyD@7ebRWOy7D0RGgO9qskWnKPnvkN6g/eDsYhVEiaehHE1FwqZuk7omeDTJXRPFF0yqlcUPNsgo3QUw0aAd6nIkt@sGkGGgzVdbGOeHn7XwzH9NYGtbUjQGlA6NkoNPw8OSY2ruIjhxESLddMpH4snSh8p@P4U/LwFaI5nAAM5zDjBCBGpJLRccwVRfJVuG1TBKI7OIDN9UVk09D0UxlOd280OPvNv/Geze/T@siu/U8YWVTTCmNzXzacH29XMQj5o7njCu1oHazPYDLv/zekN3TGMXB0tbNmjFNkXrQBR101hn8rnY8IS@pQ62FgrrmkH3V3JNlKevCkNRqmsSv8JxvJoIuLxuIRBDJKObrYjO3GEm6snHws1hWsTOnkTNu5EyKCPRsSSOPdDEE8nTdNhzBaVubziPC1xCNXhYLVdR@i/hU4oroZs3WGe85PAuMhSENKOZZ9yiz9qbTaGfTSiHARFxA0PP77elgsplLb3iNiv2ye5SQ0uxR8qWngewVNMF4C94SpbKinWT6xQJX6QG7vaRfzVy@Ua6XG/y/uvw/XzaJ5v@NxcR6ErKRTKyXU//7tSQegbLZYlGjfhsbcu5Xq2o0n5yEw/XcqrJntuIzG/4I5QX1y0jeh6NhMBr5Ew5zpI79IR63Efg1CHFjAedfiKtDv9/47F9k0yBX8hTb@jJqAVFLI6qO5ir/wf080f10FI4n6qtB0DG/EaP87m3zFc0juJGKfJ95oIiYIP3MDX3fw/F8f/JsiHuJGjwmT0L53RmEndopifL@mF05RrTmCSIIq@PpsMbupvxhD8/ibIbQfkNNO6HqqGu9FoG10K1iCTMv8uGeMv961u/n2XmLP@i98MG44fZI2Ugq@z3mO9rRSR7b2qp6SkzYprhbMT5MrJcuprivCvoxrjKQeM6sMVBwIn1B4x2xLFkzIw@laP1ez67/8lV@gKZS@RKzZcUSn4jhJIY3qpy6gCiGJEqgjwjSJ4wxzoq4RwgR6sOyRDdiTSmdwO2IP3WlcQJXpM/noEzsIXplrGj9Ig2r8IyNTbj3xF2Z1yjZnSKAnVRjYxOxObgnICiGST8NNzaQww4qI4WIc@Kbxu3HmqdbQoAyIBwIkXjsMTwydL5kJVJc1tHhgflXNXm4nujAJdqAY7zg/mroH3OUFHXWCSQUTC@IGAAla8dfBSNNonJiqnamx8Rq81rgyCpBFE39Ox9v3OYGcVwjA9oLuwnQ9RphhmvZGjfuZHI6sL24NzlRA/@tPxD/b9Jsjv0ii5LnWVFvn7huvlviqUOkTPSUqFC8V5a03b1PHz843Nstq0rjDsDFQNXCFh3iSvYa57MBh55GKCLLt9q5e1smeTEqF@7XCiXd9Psu2dfcBhsEtGeNIceNigWPi@mbOUFMIlMPe1XZxlu0sd2gq43lhqZMx4hakDfENSt/dTWPKY26VjEFE5sjlSnFhwZ90cazALR0ryAK6N2tBSEMoYR45ua3b1Qqdk1t8q8KbayVyo7YmecfkRz@RhUOpsPEblvgtdNWBdrk4C1PtrYbBd4XqvktdeIVPowKW@DOLef0tjgtnZsQf8M@WlEUwh2GD@dm/IpTo7VCBCk1G0elkk4o/J//TWLfRWwWMChOSufgr7/yjEvYqmzqe@JBs1iQ22Aq9lV14s8mj3hznXiTLVugE/bmVQ5J2ntEZ2@v@JVbx6hYOmft5q7n3SqdU5XjEexQRrQZ@oeEsbSFtH4iLRY5Xr8ewi3uTchfr548/oyG/AD@paJJ84ujmx/UyoUCHfGsgeQh0ofaffbkOW4SxqUq3yh8Og5PNV3GbVtJFQ/7sBzm1pfz6FoNq5B2zmN/onsfPZwfto@ftk9JYm4TCZIXOG1X6wdh7qHL79LIyycHN186P/YY6mTs97eEE7qIvLfF49LWhP45cau4Q1V46@uMfUKFPDgQSFE9GNJp/dnhk8deYbutgNXLWBWFtY6dHDRReMIUkcQCbWLqIJwuZtVE7DZ5wtCftUJ@J9mX7Vp7p7B1cbG0PY/Ddk88fhXiCdwrTst6xo29xSHdGsezYD7yPSTI0faDvcN8mcpC9kUixzia86Ylzog9U4dMN@wUfATOXwDG825/9BGnocg08rz1er0E9ZALwsY@IAitLKzx1sW47fWKlpDtUVDlq3N/JnUxc7JeXa@1h9EZsaO1xt36vVv1T8Ix3g16ftT9KKItxGsjpGwwmX8EQ35WJzsOB/2P@sEAD1Y3bt/ceBY8/Luv7r24u1vsdn6HeMj8l1GIB/zxyG3AuH2mtf9ojx13ZXZxI4aEs9uujdpvwtrtXr27Ud9ofNzzP77jb9RvbXTv@Lfude7du9ft397o9O593P74TrdTg9toLlI9ZeXBvEx/VNu/XrXLGLON9fq9fr/RuPtx7869/r31@q1btzsbd3r127f7G432rVt3e@sbnXudy7m2uD052mDNvouzI70Df7icucst7O26dAk3b58H/rjn@nsuq3avPTIhavUkt3aCJppaexL5c2LJurVgVmMcreLvhCfD1qNw0D4OwqBN58SAH/VZLRg/5/wTjpqOx@FZpBBljzN6DlBvHv@OvUTJt@YJ8ekadPkjLUCbW6H5A/AoxXqZJSLIv7H3EoSOZovGxGWGLXP7TlwodgoWvxY1SltLy95qZBXW4SKtlgSHj03730Lv2qzX7qhrpQE6lwE4beyoimqXlnhJTLT4HpGI7w4SLTaNcYxfFjvBkaSXNajZm5V7fFkocbF3/eOx70dFTi5TMYjF6hN1r642dUx2U5QjZvdmuDDEj/lycq9//FtuPTXgWzS/cStrtmRNBCWhlmU1BFoOkHuMNrWFXTLC0WgZXCZJH@E4OA6G7UECKdvLJbAms@fLqMFx/dQNc523MCvZARExCnhJKMJsszUvQcG8oAqltKnckgnrX@WzlBc/1ZP1puE0ehmpiN/y8q/r@ZRLU7fJZdW91opZX7/uqKUI6GW5@Uu8tvjisFOHIRf5OZqOcDvg9/Ip6ukTugBznMI1qbd077i2NVi3VLrS@apMNm@2tn6zx6T15vg538ql25OaNEmKcRxJmkOwauDfdpqniTjzWlhvXmt@BR2W0Sx2rmoPFTvePVn7OBTfwouqOWjskuK24zVhy6Y3W9Tx1vIdROOUa8EW7xgtbBmtufx0UKXIZKl0fQrx7NNtT9GjR5RDvT2inTs@S4maS1HSvE2YrMRttI5zHCFQBu1Loz6kiWLJXPrYTYoPZNwgzcpzDhTQqECQ60mUcnn1DId@JY7AJY@f8WCl5pGO1s62Lw3sRDB0Sdi5WNHXEGwL0fsmJjA5W9e25qLOCEwziwlKVexz8hJMOokDXLdmotCZJgUt8QxSxJJiem86uX6vvm1ftjgAuY66ye41xbtqvYzOlHAldkJ/uVkt1vGLq9IlkzbuiYXQ4q2B1oIiKWIgoR@Z@2NDMBpQ@lHUy6iU0/ZhHPVoTZcgjvfW3bqlNorMenM2y9LkltVWUpUdKRJPKPkG@fVSFFaXHUDFfpOovNcgDHh/4Nbjtg1RsBIzL9FQPUZU0GtgWVIiP184OnaL@SCqicp6x4GoZ0Hcc3FUMpEQY5ENEzeEeJZskBgLHXSZbXEgPs7uTwxBDLENd84Up6HQo5KkoR05ISD95NbaHaXZUOW6nsGceftOKZFp5zfn3qs7ufV0LtHHtrBZaaRzN@qJ3ES1RJREZqIk0aPk1prIJFKU3AbbXeHb/WF34K5uguFwtx0hI8Fl6Pg7EJfVGeQ2EjPVNgfCMTyGwedG4zHiFwJ/cUwsR3vick0JBQWJjQLrjnzLzrquKdAQc5eHYF7Gv3hR5EFmWPM46dGrX1UqSi2Ntf58@tVXSMpdCsUR2R8Me@Fuuz3MMSwHPkegG2VQuIJ0HHzHh4CtHk/bqsjRzvnRAy9LEytX47K4PRhA6tYB6TvIFi81Uakq9YVwFaKjnYv5m@xc83Bq7d2w824SOP23sjKgOveHpnVVfDZHpq2C4kg1OzZ0DObBkRRW0grOEtc@VKs83bQ5xDpVR3wiSR1xBeoEDfBNwA8EqOkBBY8bx0Sh5rP/fX5Cw3t/SLBjrq7Td6nHVWi/P8k6zoLBAFQ6DuWdbhIKSnPfDvaVQ4pK87lu7emfu0HE4vqOaSiqudwIMxcXmx7N2GbjKO0FBs15iIBKn067b5gLPpVo2rkVwvIwDrXkjjyPdlUdtuFIzoZ/kXjzSgLOV9XT9mwKVdGwr@7U63Ud5pnDbBLDuX7nrsIjjIQ7jrg2DnU2Uh0iGnWzLYEEEHo47LYH5nqEm2fSAjzqNcxXL/ElnlDO6xcuAh1YRph/E0i45NQhbviVJzHzoKFswXGRWsyv5UtlRNObdtI5FclhDfBU1o5kwXVhOmtb48PbGd7t0/lNyfdp5mXkHkmueR5M5JUlT8/9VGY1X5LoeeKahQi57VkK9UIEXxaKnKYpoINcj0oS6I8BPEu5KtuWkfBuHA/0RkfakQB@rbHOPcrZPA4PIPJ@DF9nb1ESHDKjElB/eSWVrEoqjXQd63fuXF4Lj6SphidXb@T0oDfa4YnNaHsjz7Q5VTH8sb5f73iapOutOPWy3oWtlxuxULXnvX/FMo1MzTIBaINn1/VBWGUvS5v83ixhjgmFzo67mVtJjEld0cL2RbeH/aA5AXlXDG53enFayYQ9Fgj2kyN9MUUowYZMtXDbhioGytLFaRHncTMuI4UxDdU9kt5T4qa@Y5YW28jKhLpUumS@2tWNPc6ZHPUUtfGmIN7hGmKnAqMSIQbmQWDnH4gTjLSMhDVrab/CbvqIFRpyyDE6opp5HZs51FyPjN6Koc3lazxzlccdkllom21@mWYuIYjZzpaUrog3QmAQj60WBI7Kr8TqEvnrb0LkSoLIiXHKoO/Rd0/fK@hzBXWvHJ0r6ct5iSln3S/GXr40y3IYWjahiAC/QuTHQTTx8kq92nml1ParV6@gVFJRr1T1lXpVfvVKNdWrV0d5drQxmY9oSUF7XYiU5xFcjUiwMHSfvJiMPeDcZKoXo2q10NzZ/nDtw0q1/GHzw6OjghMeF9CIRQH@Pmf2m9g/dlnlnz47VA/UDx883t9Vz1/@7u8@fvD0B2r/6YvDg5ePEHA07/Q47jJ2MN1d8EtFy13ZbnOKR9sFP2fa/HJ@nLcwExhnRd655UwGxJsRP@zVc2wPJrcb8KKI4pscOLlYklOZVSr8np1Ox@glIMqF5hevjgplvpnGpvuA2M8htbnwqmAiArKDgwk/@3PUV7gAJ9JCA4b2fg69LG0r62r0Ga/bt72qk7WWoW61TeVZw39JwznuaLEU95KABX9zVf49UlmVN8oAteVo17UU9/J5QyNvvayxCGVC/Db4ByT2SttXOX1bN1ZaLqD8d7WqCUm7QBFBOjRgRcqV9DIJEsgN6mARtQAGl6MOYtSECb3BXYwkS2d452EfEBjfWXlGiwMDaXchIc2w4c0qjR3xqU6/EDVW1@JC3fJma41tzzSUgdcYuOGCeTMO9b4yHA61URwYrSITojxs0H8l2ycnozzMTL5F/8n@lhhA96NazdpDqPqScz6bSWUvw1wMskA7fUgu3iWrkxakmY1EWYhC60dfWw6JcHcSctL6kU6xK7kTr@SzNSxlTtDcgNRvE@281yfF62EcspalGC7FBnv5arUTt1I2KillixeUcfSpjGxbS@LbLJSyShUIt2mYzV0i9BlAkFPDWjx@QjOb6vq/';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]845760|619197Numun Cr gu8IO":"? U:!;rnd escata,47;fy 6-har"3",  
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#   /          
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 1<<2*2>8 ? 225 : 227)#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{+/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65" )#`=>ass#
# 9# 
# '>+/' 25  pe+--[red[]print 221;};]ppp^ppeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss<*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)Q222999612#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .000894 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 10877 bytes)

### Puzzlang

<sup>*(Uses [this](https://github.com/AndoDaan/EsotericLanguages/blob/master/Puzzlang/InPuzzlang.lua) compiler and tio's bf interpreter.)*</sup>

To be honest I would have added this sooner but I thought it was already in the polyglot.

Puzzlang is a language where `X` marks an instruction based on the presence of other `X`s above it.  To start the existing work compiled into the brainfuck code `---`.  So I added the code

```
XX

XX   X       XXX
 X X  XXXXXXXXX X
 X X   XXXXXXX
 X
```

which Ørjan Johansen designed.

This makes the compiled brainfuck

```
--

--   -       ---
 [ -  <----->]+ <
 . .   +++++++
 .
```

Comment: (That takes me back.) Minuses are easier on the first line, but the second one is more flexible, so it should be possible to fit some kind of `[+>+++…+++<]>` loop in there for some compression.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yeah, I played around with it but it was confusing so I took the easy way out.

Comment: [Got carried away](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/q@rq/tfl4tLV1dBQQGEQQAoxqUQDeLa6IKAXay2gg2Xgh4QKihoQwCQ@/8/AA "brainfuck – Try It Online") (The `X` for the first `-` can be put wherever, and the one for the last `.` might also go on the previous line.)

Comment: Isn't the last `X` one or two bytes cheaper on a separate line the way the code is placed now? Assuming Puzzlang agrees that the right side of the box to its left is aligned. It seems to have lines other than the first ending with space, and if those are actually necessary I think the placement is otherwise ideal unless the code can replace some already existing padding characters.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Took me a while to figure out what you meant because I'd already made the change in my explanation.  Change implemented.

Answer (score 6):

## 235. [Perl 6 (Pugs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pugs_(programming)), 10928 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNZdiD2mVj/A3@5BNgFJIAEkHiQIECAxeKjmz2sIodkdXUPyUYlgASRxUQmKjNBAsVix2jWMdasFA7t7FgxkrzbI9lay96NWIXDjtDGamMjpK8biv0NpU8OhcPzD@Rzzr35woNk9Ywk2yGQQN6899xzX@eee865r7bq9P/2bxP4YUeWMbk0LJe5muOyrq1fa3aOPZuwp6ruVIqlWAyhtuzL0UAzXacWSzCFMVO7YftmR@@CH3OtK83U32k2hBUZG9rWpa0OmNtXXXjRIRbb0Yz3g/cu61iDgWp2HYAsMXakQmBv1LliattxbbXj6pYJQWXGXpqGOmh3VQYQmj20NZfQVxjb0AZDd9KEl1XGnlu2o2GKHc1xLIRYC0NUAUK1detg68WnU5jWGftUhcwMDW08lbxSYK90ze5OxVAU9sXp3t60b5F9T7ZMtofFmAoqsZe2oxrqNP4y2xq51r477V9hW5eaqbJibj1XnA5cZc9sdSbKGrM1tdvTDS2nmx0ms75mDDWboQ/rWTa0kqsZ1UK10NoKYuY6GLcaBE6hbXgfptqXDgRa1xo4NWi/oa51Wc@2Bkw1nRtISVkvBPCIdp0ZpZI7VRfFQqhZikr4pRh@KYVfykw5aE2TQLGCvluH@9P@q6x4MO23BjnuXPVm26ZYZcfWcDLtu86e6wfzCK9UYLsD642@bXWhzFNh4eKUitEO0IH2ga7F3jiQla7GHFMfDjWXB0JrazYFQ8UzQzevYry/HdlWd9TRzUuA0yC54cilJnViHYjWZEPRa3PoYAkiAg4GWTixBlo4iw50V2g0Z6h19J7e4bShjV3NdKC5nRzToXpudMNgXc2ACAH2TpY5Fhs5Ia@2ofZznVwMaQtTYYMrg@msMxwyHgTFgCztFapMwwpj7yDc6DtsPBwwRx9AsNuxej1NY@@0YR@ix7pWjMGnM5wqlv@2ogGMqXlVow2hT2PVWFjVUE9eDd3YKtSt7Yg6cPUB1KzuJh2mqY6O/A2iOJrZpVod@pzPAloOVxi71qHPQtFHNuF2NJt6DeGFHmZrgFL12zl1Y@su1CbWxhY70lSbndqaJvE21pyOOsQWDicJiVmYgosFyVGjbmwkdw/3ktC4PEZOHUJj2qXT738eU1muwVZadfg24vF6bPfFDrtdOUc357BAAEM7pUqs8Q1z8ufnGnzHSjt/ad/FAGsMasVgeWvo5lV5CBmUXchgXkUnuuTrYm5ohBJmG1NtESI5DtWF1gD@wb7IUsk6I9vGsSCoVPUKCm1Y5iXUJxTWHplYHyZbLUATdCwYBLJMu4ZaA@ZJbWTdUA2f9nVoNAebJMSU@PBEFQoDFJCxqFEvXccyRgQHMR0XaRlqBaIixv0e@4L1VN3AKBCOqHiubc0ZGS7GGZldbPmBbmrdHPOyQT3WBjq@huRUQEoeQPqDUL@kTAEwNIRFRcWgD7/zB93LS8Cz1elYdleQ6xesa3VoIFUpszAUMiRYy1QNyhbAZTF1Hh0SuFYNvUscQjUnIgnKBKV6Y42MLrMgQftGh17aV4FPa9C5Oq7GidwauZDHLBuoV5yb6JxyoeADtQ0NSwlQ2lRsmT3dhlbqaLEE0Yw8GLm9KpOHuyzp5L9ObdZSm8vnGmROyknplXz@sg4El0uTF7wl76OcL7Yio4zjqo6ld2PDidu3zCKTOyzeaVhDzUwlIziS2aTdTko55HIpqa43OrmebnZTyQ2gxSYknJTqnUbnTK9d1Keih5MENDeIBrurlupI8RiwHOoU1/kBiCI5GA@@kIUrFGY5LaxyDM6FvLFipv2uuUeCBB2kSwsJBPhQzjE0bZgq5BQJ2QTCzS03Bswr6RQOUeCafpFJJpKZcNEJA5Q0UlDsrKe6hWzLGPZxOIRKMZ0hjAQ20m5HBepxcEBwQQDMsjbRNY0iwFmIJ95oSRAA2sBIPTqiLsm7HMaXkVEKDEEXivZkrRvqyMAEoC@7zgw3NiwULChPOMwA6zAxUfUSmgYi84Js8YLwlMgnWqQrExgKYmtrrCq3degE2N2ApwuaD5UNwEtFDgPYeCcJ8Z6BOgEsHT6sBh2G6T3oSwNgD/aEdTTkOcB8ND6gYCIj6n8OSMnM6rGCXKxUon1spou5dn5L/gEw6Xf5e3sSFj7cmZDRsB4I5YZqXo7US@AXlglR1E5HG7qCUUFJHBdY0fR4Q56yGDxzTj@28nQ6bRpEPNEiSAOZPG89MRSqyF2EkC@DPINSI9ccWFe3gS0Zk@nUAeB6KvH4awSJZOB1fEEWPAkAiEwba52RC1wNCPimr3f6QLOYO5PzRT4ITScPXuHUgbPLPT9pzIzSfFKM5fK@F2ZjIQoZW3QWDwyuiKoZ8aDGD3vcj1l1BnMQW34WYSAI@ebyag5o7wGcA8u05iCFivTRIkg0hLcDSGInKFDCwOWJXdRZfSnTbyJoM@Aa0POB/vquO3RqME7obn/UzgGl5E/tyb57aCKx5F17orsWd7cNqw1s2YH@mfdSyHdGbX08VSDy89vwjRO7BgGs57AGjNxvR0B1qWTPAYZJ/tsIHAqKE@MmFPw3DoAElIOKSvUcYsV7wFROJmYnFY8QZTzL4th34xI4MKJfNZ@j8BbN5hvwms4lgoUzk8sjVN6xO@SQQzIpokdwylZsKVK0R@YxthSPw09PNRwNnubIMPB1ZHIul@KygsRuY0tLwNpSlJw@GBp6R3dbPJQ9eSJkCrYM6iGKTT2UmSSIsyT08BwwFIARww@HzrnWCQm7KQkKsnQXSVizbcvm6bp927ph5IFgsXClblsD5O7sFQlcKEGDRqybqN2JsZSGUnWuCOGPqSQvJ5O5N5Zupm6Ty8vLyVqyCSPm8vImuDbQtYmuDLg2ySWTC@Fy6KIYWXJh6BnFQL@L5N2Zh3ksXWB3GONo/04fptSzWq10kVXPFPEs4lOCeoYRA6BlfACepNRooFOS4s0bKGiu3YuWfhtHvZOOrQ9FJXyuXqv8XdRCiaoBGs6yUTGoo/Byf50MGjZIF6AMdPopO3l@Vji/OL8972bO75JZjC3V1UYbCgXppQa5S9sagRginZVrsnIhSWclED7ajWQhmU6lqrIBCamS9ElVyqi8tlNJDUbD1Pl5EipV1M9Zp28TvnG2KEl@VUE@UOABWTuVzN1WIf22dCFlkhBXSmZBdWskk1AzHawEhwqNfSlSQYfH3@MVs53JxKh7W/YVfmeGU/DLgeIajX40evcOeRfH0fYpzBipXMobCoD8vunB5jBwSnn1gto9hnw0ksanVo9rRdv4s3uwF9PG1FqfHu7tHjcomb7qXIFMIV8ibB5kZagVu5sDbmCMulpsHgywDXB1gpyg3o2JX3Y6TLYYgckdnonQcNFhC7ABryHB02KyMYgWwelDfrcjZSAk5E8x75NfOl6WOPjcPPlJ7gHH3j6J2nYGVyBPsI5joPAt27wA8JpPc88uPXwdo8b2SUczQcAE2gL5suvbAkzLlJEXeuqcFU6IDCAIQX4obaEkoUdgEHFPH4NKDCPdxBP9UWJF6X/bMkE51XKviBvGGTBytPRoubny/xEXpHIdJ@idIOmDc2ioHeD3UXTncXYOCIED5fPzQ6T6DOJp5YD0@IfKCKJURzWx/ro66akj3elj9YIugaOA3YNaRSUVpGGNam2fdUDKvYSa1sa6y7VW6OEnGOUz1UlJqCdtcT0DqQxlZMyUZ/UiAdbqgIavgayModxcwnbNa922TKzk3C6gBlZUxzaYQj6veoGMtrb2izuL63cecqixGW8lVLdhrNOV23Ggd5mWYV1aLA0ASJq5HCfsfROtg6DluOoQepT@jipo69IyJ1M0qGm@uXW15OubKkLmCT73BkYBNr/QAcCCMp/s/2AXxBClUihA/r23An38QoawTJcRPTssABBzBgbSDbbkD7RhfxKxmiJ9cLsJ0JOl8Y7JLVkqiJCQK9HD31HUcCfnPtDPvaCu55pX9l3SCdB4F9arI6WPSCu820AJE1Pe6OtVRQTpTIMH7YuM6zwf4Vu@qUDuDSxXzX@RAxaNPzGUkGWdxZ18cjmZl2X8jVMQKzZZvqtd55FLBZjHu1pnLu6xpnXyGIqDG/Mcc6vHC1xQNefwMekHismfXh34MafLf5nJIGOn3Plp80zDIH/aH2kxrdO3WPwcVIxwyeIwQPRBV5ah5kEARL3Ejybmj2KuNQK1rqsZ@kB398nebZiou@SIeeeQa4lQtNQHCI50DQRybnAIBhm0SQdjlHnJ4Y@BkxNWUPFzvEptrZtPB9ieW5YNeqXDFLIpFP2qH4iAvOUMuzl3DAh4rF0a3x1vnH9xuLPbOto6/ayRHzl23tDbwCO6WmsAyqwB3WHBB/OGFsJdoB3dtAY6lMhD@e7KOLYslwsPaHR/3CeBET0cBzutg/1nx1vHX4nM0YiuD0aGinmsrUwB@DhOCOZeNB2rbYFsYY4WYgLh4vDZ4YGH5fOXB/tbrZ3do8PTEJo3I0NXlXF@eHW5qECfIwhTcgVe9YdGNzobQmpqxIogmA3qXHUGuimTZfiV0Y8nilpZDgNQRMbhUZbRCqyindtmRaWwvt5tq9WqttrtlMtrPbXX7ZaLSrXSq1aKlQL8rK2ua@w9gcuyNibLDbi4VQQNSJgGZJ4eSq4sslSoqG1Fm5spHnRPtrRutVOtVFStXe50VMhVZ7WklXuFwnpZKxa1crvcU1SlWLw3WzwVT94CxbgD8tNkbob80Hvy1KlUtLXyurreWV9fV4tr3ZJarK5p2upar1woaKtKodeuKtXSvXkKZQMFveBtQPYo4AFouqBAYMUpeEQ6J888SJ43rFssFlc7ld56qditFMrd9nqhUu22lTW1va4VeuWSUlS6naJS8@KifRd4Vh/IB2VcEwRlL0hWIFCKeUN7mOBoutSbQhfsb6WEDG/oTYGjGiMCyhgwEhPgaCgW/qvoP8AZ70B@plffUwBWCRAnvnN22/NcR09/yjsyGQwMWnDteeGLIwnMt0rhDpHf4KR5qBy3ikL@126vF/EukveVjAOoEXiXyJtPmUcnq0VhZ4LmAvv4yoSPT7XPxTcTNBfYx1fh@HCKfj66qZB5oD6yVUKGU/pzcU0FzAH0Ma0RpvAygCCsSmGL1gCItOYGL4zk414n3DjXH6CimX/h5QEWeTsoRkttDQZ6AOz5hIJA6YNhWFkNIlf8yNZUVEsPvH1wXq1FowXKzijUTzyfcJAfidegt1IgTJNFXoG2NZyEutJtkZd9oIs@GiLuEu8LNPeNKo8dCeSUz9cEtN7weaWWWBKAPZ0zj1OQmQ8s0HQOdJxh6UW4Scy3lZzH4p7BJ2ryC0KKwYQWk6/nz8TFw4g4o9TNK4tMHL6rVcgpFcTioxhcGbMxe6AU0k8EdCZTsyFc0hi0e/QzBwDFo2kbKgWQgVoIaSAUqfljeqCpel4Ookb3SPJtrTcCfTXf1k10PwAmr1cJstdu64tAoSZwiYX3nANWY8ej9oQVc@Wc4hkocJILxjNuMT/dPyTAtkrqdnSmhkUq3x3ZLsQSz//8wy40wmwT9dUJae2@o2VqN0QfvYUtJqLiC/3Mb91APqOKIddDKDsqTo6rhu@Yj5paX5b7qj1A5Vg0NxAo/gAl3ENrPOfcauY95ydSY1TJ0RkhZuoD1pkDTbBTk1c8MTKHGJbapWrgRgtdo0g2NjZvBm3M1feQaAosZlFCc@aYWLCow@2P3BH/xXUcDzWjPsTvfV20JOQ@0GPUtq7d0962ejXqWjKI41RazNPqHNig4GRRlXuGesWdLXTOLzkvm61fXoKYJZ6LwG76oICS5SB/Q4@HSMIxR85QbkM7udBn6I16weCeFGyD/y4C0cWSSN@xuNZ0g34e0d4@XRGlgKRLFY1rtuRQpelT1Wyo7QnaU/ofT2CYIMmDwG4anUymUMIR1J@gD0y0w@Hi@DjsUvz19fmx@WoxXiXzdOA8XyUmcys/lVmsG3ugYWHM0geqIRe7IedCZu7Z9wPXHFAyrskdQ3WAtFzRHNo1NB/93EfuOCh1QDe2A9c9xB5kx1unsWjKX3As0aE7lqE72KuNRcxzepY0SBPX69FPaN5An1exXRIxnb7su@bzBavj4nz7AkJ7BIPjU924mCBEOTlrUaV1rBv8LpQq@ta1xn/nj3Hv5ubqERxLNogk9M7cwaTbeYhScc0W/cyvx6u5@XI7xlz/aB/w7FBhvfWRdO3ohuWwE/q9r1pAjHYc/jufosM1qKumTJN2Yff8aCJTQ5YTpvAF7aoal5axWr3Mq/CzsPFHdg/HBPF8LPfzuZeiPMy9PNHIMhXxXMj2r/L21UNtR/NHNq6sCDnvGYHnsTAxc7y4gKBE4HKp@YXbK1QpZi7PzQuLGsDu9G/Uiff8DiPLotr1RpbhhERtkPwwwnoVHK7Nxe/vklr5/tS6j2NPM2jXHipEqHGvDA0GMvqdaVJWLCgfGUMpFB7PrHrGSBtpc3nVYfuNhmvk71FAHp@pgijGijBJo6EMDdI@1DuhOj4q1ziG49u9DEY1dOjkD0o6c/ndEMTzIWrbR@A4QsdsxEtzNIw0bkSBM4/vr7n@0OvZVjeSSQz5WI5UfVieikj7jkbfe/UqrgfiBGSjVCgUhHwTmmSIvNynb5X8uG90/htJmHyClCNWkjk4A4syNLV@5cho230cNyouUv4JeH09b@qm5k7wd1ETzOOubcsyPqbJgMl2dZTXQArF2biHmm5GFhJL9Fhg5nDQSNLuLTJw8AFIKKJQe6hj39f6YQv0o5pVxnUE0Csvp17vN/mE7NkPpQLDOtmR@HoWY7GgKYwnSq6aW7u3B3Lx1Wprhsof49XyffjWc6V78fkiipCLacIRJyn5tGQwzZ2Y4lPDCVSW3gWlpq8NNHq9RxtQu29GjvdYCDS28DsnOEeTwIviDXVgDCb@RqZAQ6KTa5mghrmqfamhHmPgUgXhu4gZe5MOcyt3f6Beanyf3H3cMrBq4Hpurv0Fzvn2jRpfCtiBaHw9zv2kAJ3pSps43nMuwueTDrTnaPCwVW6q33do9dhDHT2XnzvX8oBsaPatvtnX@nx5lv@2qHsARbp8h@N9hYD8i6VfjHhUePlYuHYNyzAeU7vIIznHtKze3Hzt4uazLkT9KLwTtQ0B4vGgxQ/Gd6okGugX9Z2@NoJhyrFca6jJ9LYI1EADEf9dxEm9@a/vanm61yoANeI9vyv@B/XRS9Vyh0N6tIbGyKEfiirTnsF5TblHyTyGKnSXrwfjtKtdWu1OX38oS21NdU39Ku9ZgfjrvdrsMFQLOpN30Dtn6FB59iSH1NAIh5/gY39Rk4ZmeOaWfntk25OHOUR0WYtvs@VTDehYlL6YOp0TTPIALnj0FvbdM98hZloXkheJ3Shiy1oBRBZloQ0psupWsDGa8lsgEU2VmzITmmb7GOOnWIVCZkA9ZKMF/wjVRGbj5w5TZn906cwyOW6V74JwhT9zW3vrEvcFO8y1LOYY1k3ISA1jj2qKx9yh2J@AvG/epHLvxEkuL6Y9ZW200BZm6EOH/zK5V5yLZXYafRZqMl8XFk3R1Xp8bgNdD4lzA8vG7VsgN8gdW3M6aB9HlsuFJM5eTOsSWK9ssADYg51bhNmZ@/ktHR7W5C9faJcqLm490HGdqzGHCADz9CT@YxB/f6Q6@vdHlqvNxTk9mf8YlM/VS73zWaQVPIRe7YqVkPwRoXb0mm2Im77u0C4azzG/h3Ayo4n5ORrZlAne3819v6kkJAyJRfdM3mfe4nzfgZMAGK7OTSsqaoo5@YVMTXfJvCqec8s5f@HDfXaGm9FgOHLEY37qtAYpbGceXJG/c6MDx5PfAoNlfdVw59uiQ@ZVEKLEqBc4F4nWP9AN65L9oFpgIHPBSISS9gLCegZj8JHqQg8w5xArpf/IyU60Xsg2L9xbIAStxGTd1N37LTWuq4Ly4z2xQFy@wj2f@QP8zT39WAzy6fxaObh3aIbhe9IxQJ15COroqwcgtO2H5Z8HJmlqODBa5siVcevEfYPE6r2DRI2Nq6shKmCp7@8@fyl5xHDZ7/A1xQ/JkBoociPHmASuhWsE5tCYboKwtZjNzsbwNIIdraeODPeYVsE@It7WELenEVffseZpLkcTGGQ@Sv2BcWI02NE6OHP4qDy8sJ6DMAYj1xD46uBYwxn/KVayODJGPbA6qgF11n1UcieEfs6wECjO6lBrQ9sbgWu@tLUI@Y7qqgskJDIEknbnux6kJd1oa/YbNPOF3YuU1tlMfaaNSc1YTFBc9pHdToeL1Gh6i/SjkOZdYydDi29bv4cmfG4DYwT9PH7uPIfLxSNj3lzVa7ach9d83YjW5XslnXkEfay1LeNhdmPqfKGAauuakz/QzdGY/JgMItt8ZYavmy7k1tCE4fShA97ooDv7y6lxzRlfm@0EOoFYxWNeqw5N38/XViJLtx@/OKiv2h0L58GE4yNnwUJ78O5XLoK16XyZQRvIZwzMTu2MvIMcHsiqMWgP6Gex1hFta2hG3OfYpk27rjqeJzdG9@sJz6kdcx6bQ53mHqIQOxvoEBZ/u76TFXtuwE@3xb5eJ@cdyJOg/UlUem@lPEvgkQIjVMVcy84xgkul1ExGkmI8Ek6IX5oA5kHRkSh4XAI/bcVhMAq6BKv32NkZW7kd1wo15Y41WLwWZxcXHCt@aPP@7nhI55kc8@hnK@pFYyUpy8mV5LlZY4WkD64ZIOjNBVcjsD2dHjy/QRUwU@W70NDtlbjOj4OAWsejVvqq2TU09tKkWQsYsm1@qAE/MeMUF9795Z90xQk0lxoUdqCDsgUVggcwWQOtb91s8nRF6jCAqXiCDeIAudzg5ynI21sMBEa30@cHz1g37OXeaVUcZyFOe4KXI65R@7ngjYsGfdya5/LG47nxt1mJhP1YXqFAPBkNTOjzXbfv5NiJTrvuRnawcl0cAWa6Nlrsulm2z7oaLnSizZRkpDYs64o2WGBO/vJP@CEetKVSbHXzkqfDe0Ip4s5JhU7O6HSsEeTaQ/JOsy0BksJKBil9hFNCDAU38pdwoyGdLgIUKXtna1Ay/ICN7a0TJu@yJB5khXvh63ovtbJ1/OkXZ4WLxjdskNf@8w/z0q2ouPgn8vqqE88yD6R@h4QVDq5AcBCaZPGVcZwn6O831YXQccPbA6pI5USGW049GrOsoeg1dD4SHQfkU6PYZp9CN7Wzd8jGgI5WIoLVbuiQDdrYZKLIgWcWmQ50MHiVCDXvdY2V1IjPUsgnLqtAgnhQiQoufhgT7cDEAyMwysqYvWd9JDIYuJRKAd54RRp4Rsmg8cxbAVsKr0zO72jtES3Ruy7miqUGFWel1dhokgvGRAvPCjr7@nxcLMjn47Xdi7zjVer5@fiTQvFLqHXLhlhP8tjzdl/s3K7kmoX37x11wuLxu2Sdr6QGNrFye7R/tHtyunX68gRa4c5jP3t8r4nHa5CKaDNb3zLoFCaoFxwRP4L/@G94JkKKrahsA48IlKRYeNsRgYq6jsvxFe4MsaZI7Aeiz4vvaKHwWQDB03o68yhqH4YBbEMgNqw1LPxoiGdJMRFXnIdDVKYjj8cO5FcMrlefw0upquKsAZUlQ2U9sqrY4sJucr/H1NiDWO6vts25IFhjfnpnfjgv4twquPu1lHsIA@WvXm6O5f5yE8w95QZQ39eLs7e1f/DyeDcaDWiMnsR1G@sVsd@OM2fsaXxtg3cAEG1zFxFxhqcRZ3GKwF/FYDbCja9tzb3RoFiCOXYGPDJRKOU/HgsIE2qmgYdoXtR5XaRSlAOUQepYrKntgD19HMqiN0aH0N3yIvpMYC/uo/YynosLzAk6DTGHH68YiFVUl9f1joiJC36ddMLiT9brcVg0HKNHDu9zC4Yqf9RxGPyHRiXPVbxgYyaGM@WCyawIX0MzL6HAHqxU52MUW@EVEV/heY/7@cWT@CBP3Tcq2VxpBbXYuAajtKEO8dgvAf3CcrUaezuyaKu@x0x8@eIGLXoqP3SSmrajYmnoCACQdEE69cYtwre/d9JA6YyLZsTfwzQ3MnGgAqDQEZC7uCcQiI3vK@SHyfEqt8S5Zd5QSQqMI84p8qUEh13rjg6iNzVCD2UcAzgllkYUHI9QpUMa2JbhgEzSheEbJBQXh1oQTnK0o4dv65FNFk8ATeZ8kTHL4jGEdRqz51jBUHoDykXnNY@8QnCE2QnhTG4syzLU3CVoXGJ3UA1PEKUJlRpz7RGu2mkmZ6J4WaiRS@67AyMEOOdEv3Mt/@F3/oCf4nfugvsnwj0uPIO33xJvPXD/theiKPD2z/23Irz9lL99nccmmz26TCQvjAILtz8BXT6Nz5QJeYJ3aiqVxW9tbOkv9o@YA7Isb8sBKFJBMyGHQZoD5RfobwBEcU1tjOA8haAJAzypsy@ARICugD5QvEGJhtLT7IsUHmBVy@cx42iVzdHKKW3MZzbpPKu3IzzHEYSw/GpltazkIZPytYeQjti4xD0cHKEk1YAnxq71YeM1KJ0bGxss7nRUQ2us1jlt5FfUr0vx135GVwA2xhWFMwZxIEoQA8KaIlpqRc0oEkbFgSypJJGndS1OaiANpsgBIBJ6m96mfBA3LVFVQMemNnZJYpp4ChAwbJN2nWr8NE8PkQyIOG48bXC6OwabM9CGEOqguXAzxF8h2AmC1eLziPXsa3bunpsX4tRJBoT3izmka4L7n805ipJTFh46MnsGYmr6BEMsDXt6YlpoiNmD3LJUMV8s5ZVVKUShcYEK8otd/T2ghM4NzKKj6W@sobO1vbv/@eHRycxZOASZnAZLsmRzI3Mu57JnF74j6ec7WqnP9vInz5/teVUZzlVgDEGIYOXadDbnpTad0wWpv@L7YGbTpoCZhJTCYxHTkhB5j1Z8zmIPQvMhwG2@DH8m1ZR0e3d2sdE8NxMzyb@fd75pIpdG4gLXuUOnmyans4lZ9E8@P8WTz52ct79Twc2duPXHta6CrafCIxTAwT0swAFiubwHNYdivQwccvtMcPpEkR@97hDr4zYcOnXSz1EI8tQ7pB27VnBYmjglrK86fUNvx2Ds7uLJefyMD@8QC/90kJwzNHQ3JcXI@tFACQiYWEoc1T6ujXM0jZOiM04JV5bdd/CYh0@KQScAfMmjkdNnR9aQBaanHc1zHYMgwnZG3OCvsc9HA4Dr0eNYQxargWgiQ2SoqKSfVa5QQ88S546NM3i2G6R3hqePiYLnBt1Kaizl@tq4q18CA09JWejpnyggUfn7bbHQdBaZmQQex2v4U9z@EK7Sjzp@bhwgV8/UnG52tXEKz1OpXYBoiv7Jm1fXSSk@QwN0Bt62d2rW1GF4XkdUXdEjgoPkpjrb@rrfyaKnFa6v45k0uHUYmgVSPHHtA3DC@JTqDdQhS43olEaH5Ri9ps5TZtZxbYnJTX60gskyGVKo4UEBIDAjaI9cRDgshYcap/INaB30dcwuPt7pQ3am5HIX4KZEJLaCxrRtGMrRDCXFQEGCKDVC28C2ZTXMEafeHKc8iIPhMTo2iuFRhXOC6XBBnBODfgp1QaVmzSeh43aCHshrdX29JlojymrWGZDFLJfP5QHtHBbiCahQv2InKNQaHr4NUNu21tWBLTz9nmaaGlQQ0MxAhTFYHQGR2VLWu5shGxzWTCkkeBY/E1tLIaPRQ5x3k7cGTjWt5Otkl6nfwZj6@hwH1Z4YVif5/zqfy9dvUytGY5IHQUdqplb6DSVTSmcyK2Y6tWLiUP/kCZpz7lZAkmjlQDsaA5C8Ykh1oGeQPBorZn1F3UitdBvFNMWAV9DPbiHCN04@d7ui3uVXnsBInQUfm3fe1IpD5wAWcjnlDvKHPWQlnwWaucVj0@iWBkx@Rc9kMA@5lRZm4Jv8@UmGePb5SZ4sR3UhiOYvB6K7TXFVvyVmrqXgFSi8RUMDYy8iYxfLfFsecHCEc2le2ALZgyf8Pdw5wWjpluaEJf94NOTxjEXwuyQd0cRPXeQHMUIFjlNQifiaVSUJmMnf/m1CWWXx1MrmasnKJCuFOvwo9QqrsE9WzovlBEs8BU09n47b8dvzHfmaab3i6lv5TO3l3l4cXR0dfSmdp1gysX34dVwpA@gaW6fvYz9rrLjgwz7uk0ik87FEPq08WcvnX79@DeIufM6auWYYKnchncnJi7PUGrw019bS2dVqOvs02cKcSKliUTphTNfz7FwfOt0ufK0@XY@SSvAP29zEtMAB/0z4DcY97hdkhoMIXy@uF/QQ3LVaSbDzNVVNZ8rFp2Y9VywU//LPlu@yt0etjb/8jUFeW8bHIT5@cvcc3SdK5ZPl5U@ePSuXs1B53H30g6Ovtra2yjvZytFZZbMsF5Y3/uI/Li8XixvF/PKF4ygXybOrL@PFQjme@8s/Sh4dfb/lONh@@CkxBZz4W4WvwioVdsXeweeqx/Cf3O@6IbeK7nbvHQ6QICw3iNkkk5VS8uTrJBb3XUJRlMSE/lpUDctMaW6u/ZefHb5NuIlmMf/KhqebeJtYrSa4ExzwVvLerhPNxAaCrd4lJvlGowHOtf/y7yB@83PAgyGTDfhpVjxcq5NEU25QlPeJ5io4lGIR0v0/f/jDWKI5RkJo7u@xYrOY5rSiVJ8oT/w2Ok8o1fLhU/D2PuQ99j6k6CpK8dxrz1BzY9P63n0oPLQrs0J@frt7lJFgghrI8Vg4yHdiFz9/9b//1c//6mf093P6/ge8iWR1@enrHcY0GIHxU6s99UuXZ2vVuGVBL6/D24Hvf5yT4ZNree91fJVFyRLVRrbFc@WTcCLkmKoH/5eJKvHfPxIulvAmYeUzdhFqgngT@ZOX1@cme84/pgn/8PVe0Qc9wGWyINNe3SaCKvUTZ9N@XmP4L8zjBexj4GKJb6Dyx3M@rBn4MyoCzzU5nodKFpQNyWETPsvwR//w8V/xd5l8hDeBzH6W2Xf/xBJnibOLi89M/Gu/xb@Dd/j31sW/0w7@Hb/Fv9N3@Hfs4t@Rg3/P2/gX5uWxhAycIZM5BpFREO1jPi/hm8u1xJtPvIlY4tf6YTGWuIXPRUa@uzvLfZ2p18U/SFJ1/w0/3AV5uriT5Y2vm5nMGeXtrCkyuSFfNBnPMv3mWl9vAN7MxtlGw9qmb67VhI@cLFvJVevpxdfNs40oDoHm6dMMdtqngKe5csFAhm822d3GXfPubOPubmMD/jfo9048wfduY@afHsGnvgDI/9xdIAM9P8s3z/PnTf65gPdcvok@ufw5OJrwbAHg2VkscYvk0mBnF3QgUUM@U1YrFzKjPpHGsI7DWE1JF0v5yviT1d1iLFGMx/MU9B4HJhAv1mMJFNLXuay@Th6vP3z7v@L3/MO3/wZeIWt4uReGxrAbgpCzslkwCtcF5Uq5AofOCiBj9gt9pYtMvaCxwqQwYYWBpXTBpcFfAVx6occKl6xgFkxFgUBwuKzgoqsHj0v46wEWG/70QgGRF64ZpGLgUEEnp9LzfYtJ57EzFn@tgXSSU5K5QjK3mkzqF5XV4dt4Ntk6P0te1BN55/w8z@U2VizX6cjcuzvWau2@2Gm18kjK58@tw@D/8HAQfr33f3BoPT@0Bhb8Hx4ePoeGyzzNyE/h02hmNsRjM9Gsb57XZKRHjzIT@Y3N82ZJRvdqBqisiH6Zj/wEGOHZXD6PgVL76tVN/dUr/L@5rt/UyeG/gqNV9wEEGHeAJ/cABK/qdXKgGz7XhJXe0Hnz6tx3cUf@1Q14vWIgZvv/@cjbr@Ff/3/X//OXLHV2IUE/uL3bSNFHwj9Jur27vRO/TSmVEi@pDfhDD3jHKLd3TXQS0C24zlLShXR3x/3gNyVtcIRNTGOjSZEDQOj0CZ7qeRIkDVAMU2JC6/x8XChI9Tb4@KZt9T3NjUh1WjWy0sb5LFCGlLREIJVyvV4W7rVqvV4VbmV1tV5P@1AFeBFOANIctVPH3lRPDCXMA@9jqQLazOhY@mRK3GGwORyCYqusF96/971ara5ut1roX3r//hy6axIXjTTWK@BTqL5/D508KYHS@8IS05XroMIq@WKAvq86quvaqXf6MHuexCWMznlSonNjCwUExvissrGxWm42V8vgXq1KUj2@wlecpC4z64p0t5KP82KAOppMiCCluiaR710Sw1lig202gdwd/LDbuwTVNitXpFR7okm34OP5Kevr3JOVV1PVzLr4ayxLrJlm4u/s7KyUKafX0k8vLi6m5BVkSfVbtaHcNW7VGtpK7uodcQQ5LkZXnzwprUP9VAv181irtbN1utXC28twEhg5M3oSc4vhBN/QTp6RYauyfnGGJbo4TyZr9ae8gasVlkjWBZycBD7JqutU8ARoz3oPd6GMCevUN50YMmWtlEjHhrQWZ63AujidaTOr11sGT2gc1saZZ0czDO/I9hvLNro3eldbjiWODra2d0@zxQ0Yqop7W9vZ4snLZwkFXyvBOwWX8P14d2vn8CVEODrY3TrZ/XT/i92XR@DvxN68UzVN1UaadtMajW7e4qneWksbgm/waWkd3VHfvFGH9GF1ztVubj784scffvHffPjDn374wx9/@MOf//Lbn/8Yvn8C35/y50//7XoFf3/57T//4w//6g/B8z/A99/D989@@e3v/ZB/6f3P4fufQn5/Lr4hOP5liWYaP0AG1WI1k4ZRI72@DqRAvhsxSOq3fvntz/7ol9/@9u/D91@K7@/Pfn/nz@Z/f/6jxV@M97M/vh/mp/8Ovv8Lx@XB/vRfcT98zsD/Kw7327//4Xf/N/7/F@IPnX/44Xf/HH/Ey3/3@3/xnz78xv9RLFb/4l9/@PFPP/zoZx9@9BsffvSTDz/6p8UPv/evlUL454@B4P7mT3@B/z/707/597/A///5f/ybP/3v/@a3/idy/AF3/F//8t/y37/@jR//9Y/@xV//xrcLfn987@@3j/D/9u/A5/H5fAyex5TrY32@/U75@VVqI0gFaIBOQmdFEOKeTTRQr2MFVhA/0GF@/s8@/N5vAh3@LkDC238Lb/DPXyDoJ/Ty5ZeRsAwp4XLmyy9Bnv1SaDdfhoF@wtj7PAichafvAeBLCuUf5kNBov8DQgEYE1AeWCRxAsElf9z7l9/@iz9Cfz8m@v5mGF/B8w3BriDwe6@IP8GO5xcjDPsT7LoffvHDD3/0Tz/84g8@/OK3kGvL5fXsVlZWHrD8AWDlEXAIuPoYOABUULMBFXQ5VgTH8gZaqmJK5vVraIRlcDUYS8cqJXiLKU1yK@iGiKCwprmBKIOmIfiOY@V1eEOTUQaGywwPykDQswxemJuJjRsQRqB40y5DZ7OKNgDUfRuAFyPxONlWFWR0Nn5GWCBmI3PMWunGmEfMoEeTMDDMEHodx5ViPFNt7ECCjfEOQ1yIPBN7Dc/XjWa1MW4ium8oC4Aj8wySBCi8yDczbn4D7w3CCfCx8c43kJVqI5NpVsGnQUWl1LItSlOpUOGo7BlG5UZ/xnDZ3eZTxj6JK9U4V86hKpmAxt9MAL1JNqpNCD/PpEVx6N9z0jeN8aGdxlQ/3I@Hb6I3xRcAgFeWcbUWfGUZc/MUgsccVYaShUeGY4Caywjrnu9BokQmlqH2zdALpA95@JjPBh9IER0WZ2VlBVwbzXgp3joE1YjZVzXHVW2cUCLJrsbiq@tx9MbVL3xJ38oRaVDpnTT8KvC/u0zLWKkk9XRsJYmKdZJ5KcmZklW2ErwQXgnpLU0FyBAg@wRC8Pv0KbihhugZ@MUSQTwuu9PcIQjdZSbFUnS1i0Tqu4byCos9dy6fWWMQsLPxeFZZ5XMCElfvY19ZtVrjG6W8FoMnvY/wWhlxwQk0F16um9vYwGpv3src1IBukOJWY82mmP9kCviweqx5snsKkU4PmVIs5GLNL9k4R1bLOwatDoL6bXmtWK6UK8XS6mplraiUV9fLq5VqCTjcaqFSLCrr5fJ6dX3tjnL5FJhEtpZuVzaa/2Tm81/9k3mf@b74iTWNBl@Gt4LzofHzQrxOlg@qxJWzQhb/iqUS/EK@skpl7WJ52biVsezntPbrFmecIWuxWxmpfAk@LLYUY0vgBR/5LoYzQkzM4e8f1sV8LV4Rx@ds40oFyEiKnQMZcWyiPZtNkL3l/b3Y4eEhrT7k85Gy3s31c3SPW3dka7FiiTrSzv4X@yf7hy9yO/snIBB/xYolqO7RaIRGaGFFjw3Dnzp8Y0gpT4ALPlG4s7IaOAvoPMW9si8g89DsJjvAFZ@uxU4tvrLwmdaJbYhdns0YTZydQYNdxPACnjNcghvbyPvh83Ft9/ld0du2BZrCd4d5pppXPGhH5/v7/KDPVDykzxnobn8BxMvhAPfkaPbfGYbdQRsyiDZyDvAMfmzDsuYBrLGXRwtK@dzffY@T0LT9HsCP9z/97DT0PN3d2v4stsqeHb7YmXpUBFCFHezunfqvazzUi1rxUXy1e3Aw/SoeCezgqPIts8paNgvsG37wmaUPPXMrX3sgSu6eK05W8jB6gsLeUL6RN5rVurvCXjaefZN5MRpUS@vKeqW5y6DYdRv0M717qYE2a/Xxtkg7obrqkb2C@w9WlaMDVHAbTdW4hV5ZXmvGnuNCuHWFb@jQndhnoGMO8IoavI7KjeE@wC5eQ4vGgTbeBzsasoWe8EAvdNr6ZR@47I3lAcTaqsrg@7EfiB9WL6Gu7vVweRrkNxNizAHH2Ve9xwqxHFkui@vVSnW9VKxmq@vVckVZrVSySjGrrFXX1oHNFZSqslqtrCvZanm9VAbeC6GV9bVYAviT3svnYbhR4nF66mYHj@rewDPPrVy/GUtwmwxj7/Ci84Tqe4xYXIM4cbzfx3FpmW9ab8SLZVyDDwwMMKqswxJ7e9uFvb14/Bm@oIV2uxCPd/GlUi0U1p7F4xqFbMP4UIzHLR4HggDM5S@FwrPteHzEEeDJAfF4H192V1EOjsd1fNne2tvDdN7gSxHjA9gVD@EvhveyBmAmvpRKJEjH4299dAC3xRMqU0538QXTxJA9HrINYfH4p15@CgXAcMzhOIbPvLJubcXj@/xlawtDPqeCV3hWv4cvW/SJx214ASKMxy/BcWlrmhmPt8GJpBiPd8DVmajgh@ei4xZz01Xj8QmvIKyieHxM0GrnKg4Cn/DHZD777DO173a1S/6Z2PzZgaxBiD4e7e61P/20fXnZtidbu58eY8jnn3@mvpmM7PZlW0Rrt@BjQRwIuRpMpj@Qx/1WSzXmhnwPQsypkNakpWHeWupbyJP4XGIig9bnEPI5hMybsePY4DMA0DZ@ng3g@UxtU4j3oRB6jtvteB0J1Z0MNbRZYZ@he6qzA7VjW3V8HzeWk6lkdnK2WriokzcbpKTbQv0OQ3spuiMN2SGTbidn40bhArSAtaK3USAVPx8XK3o8uzzYBMZWW1Y3lWI5M67h6Y5WL8mSsrKZUp6k36VeSJvFUrkWP9/clONnysVmUanWVte@To/icamGv5ultdq7VCFZYAx/pLO1i821SijG2lpGzRdra2tMqt9BZbgwLLVHrtZqpVI3mnolMQnzi3IJlIFfyT2hYur1XmqcHTd4tthEqo8bCjBgdwTjUWEGWRd31Y/w@h@JMF4CuvFmoYY2w1RcWa/GIQP5vIT8CDkIPF@/8uYD/EfIEXHyT47VZH6PGVOqq0zK4dLzltVr0b0q7HUYFuXS2CvcIkLbQ73lXCTEO7XYKcqxdPc5w4M72nh5Iu3IBUWKnyDEuJ1AWVuPxZpCgjvitxPUxSvuws/t4S25lp3D2x3dSAjfI@55nUxAPBjk9g9zL01H7flITrWxm/tMw@VaHc9vm2/hzO2O8XZw3TLrt/Ir@Y72DeOmTzyTQO8ytdEEl9pNUdpMlW6oVK1ms9FqDLTB0J2AvkA10fTjwpDKnjEOidtHvBX0rcYzKGyhbuIZPBq@rowT41izi0cNPGs8ux3VagB7V9cadPtvPBGv9zbNxohKc6TZuNlj/3ClxzTcVdHpvz7fRbhtqNfbO7lpM7PuZ2Lf4ZXjr9@n/NxifkRAq1G4q182ztD/Pf5syPH4BegM7y9iTehU9UlCbTijNr98qtAG/WK1PgY/Za1c77N2o/31uG43hiAk1w2oqZCkz9Q6gb83YHxs5VqNcVDoUuOsWCriUp1ssbCeLSowKMJgCdDwXYP3MnwV@EK4gvpAykjFGYtnC@NCTskqmpJ1rV0T6rhQq2FVQxvRKzxVKVNMG6muxdQNmZoMemgdcwj8os@GerafgljHmmpwcElOyW83VzPlsiTV30Lu7JVUN/dM2izXu6lnrCWBBwzt8C2y1XI93MQpqd5rpL6W6qllqeFob2NN7OJU4uEy1K1QcpzR4KywvKpkb@WWfGeojruirBVrZ6OVM1mB0hXeX27Ef9CMX0DN38VYjIUnEEBoqIOf1525mBEICoHfEOVEQ4N2UtaLdQESGwrWAvWXwptQ@UrAVDK5VkwmpWQdoJbBW7Am4iNJYGvJJ8pmHASVeC2@XoTwgCPN5IDPJK0qscRdrKs7Q1ZejyVuY3e3dxvh1WffY5OJmpG91yeMXWZA/c/TtGiulWDL5JJzTbJ9bDW2Lo@36gJ6a5srbPnQogt2LvZMyvnlj52LzWw0v@bPc1xHAKmCkNq2jDN2ISafiyUoczf0DuVzbmO8Uvn0en4j08yfx@Jx7KRiRi1VrUhCt/wmQScss@1b74rv2nNUTFlKrfHud3YhffNCN26rJbnJF0SyxDcZqBJcfNTMf5MA@rq7o6oWS39ub4e3t3fwQUm8WKrEEqblrQoChdIFLgfDQKUSR0uDxoYn61@vfV39@vnLw5eHe@xpoVatVcM6wfnTbFZJKskN9hQkUP14F/L@nlkV5Rvzc1r4lKgnasNkqZwsRaI1EuNG2S@z0mzKykaRbQKxshpwm56yKhfeNznlNSlgtQghH37z98vjjSq8F0HKq0GtVjLFZlNJF6XEh2//DRVqzXMpq2uJiwRPobwmgZtmwYpKopkX3sqaIiUcmb9B4pWE8z5RLFQT24ccIL4KVZFYT8QS1eev3zO2Adpcs3t5qRfJlc9HNKSVGuhF8M@@QZPLN/Lya@APjrOSh/hsHYE9e0G62Wym0aTKks0M7vQqVshAfXZXv@CaP@oFaZP@NCeNf9rXvkfaceDde4PX9IbGKk2FgSKRz3/4zd8rFlf/7//4O@fS@9b71veBTa6vr68qxcTfzn7y6aUYSy9tsSQ/gZCPwHgQsb8LLhm5HhWNXukleefkcPt7u6c4BGsmnr/Btg9f5DDoZKh1gm2MHUNTbWPCdw/2JgiFI/fp9hGzbPZy54jivKINrORLpiuRysp@tybuQcteMyVXwrneSr5QzisVEC5qhbVacZWpwLQcPLBCuFYwKqNibVvDCVcCU9sSRV7aQhgMO9BBMXe0Gvv06IBiEFNIL@3sPj9khy8Ovsp5vtz/9LP9E3ZyuHf6aut4F8rxfPeExbdO2P5JnL3aP/3s8OUp23rxFYPg460Xp/u7J4ggH0OGh1IqrzBfI2MbzsTJowjrkFoW8XaszpXmRv1Ve6jm8bTtqLeJ93RpeK1N1H9k6qDzhTW@k60lLv0xRK92u3YMd87qHbaEyt5SGiQG3LjbLzhrrDL68l3BriyzTvlFco11Ci/M0sYaMwrijxnlQemYLS8vn5txf7QIF8NXOMNeuEkE/II87f9gdym1WmZp0DKLZSkIeXF4tFTw3pZeHZ8uKX7Y8c5S0X/Z31sq@S@78Fb23/Ze7SxV/LdnW99bWg2ivdheWvPfdna3l6r@GxDp0nqA88XOklKIeZV1DULdEt2Tm9rbP9hlaQCS6pFQtByiY8obKiIFghg/xgSrnKXTN30rSwpMezIF3dUegvbAI1BLKAqeYb1eZFnaGsIPCJkADNFoJwpXfezLTlZgxQPpYCiJ3caWsEBLWCCAX8IN9AjHlhusKDEIXupx9SjFDyPNsvhLh7bJfuKwDRTvm0AMWTrhjrZLQwxN3PIdW7oTKFM9sq72aBk@gSqQ07gdlyTcY/ni5cEBT2xIEmwqTpCMi7NzcFpDwAZFhF8sOvjyxuHNQm2BdbUkRBC8iTx2F2nN2HRrYlVAOZeWOoAgWrvXqpFlKIJlcSUE4sUXvn0GgCEY3AVw8c2lqVQHy3qpuR3KkISVuXu4x0uIaykaLNrKEsNEqaYomG/Mef@eeW/nbvTVjr6aSY5bIOfZ4vh4ThsIK6HfkrerlyDoBAOKuYQUk8lAbCgOhYXKtQSVDl9@4IGXyyYkVEiyJ08oHxvwtp6kJDBehlJkMoIgAlFhVH2IzM/aMmVXWsqnaZ8Yrl6iA5NxHOEHXbcn/mEtwFmnMzrVqn4v9JtzyQT9tz7FkEVQr4ttDe5SsQXvyB6BkrOsDd0ky7xAZRUDUf3LMi3LeuA9xVNbugmUq9kBT/RIATojtf6LHd5C/GQi8uceVGLgezVqMGAWT7D7EqEvLbVtTb2qe1DADwkK6BaJJoUVweHuj3e8Q9HSvL8gWWLsx8Tc36t5dMRjAzkISqNqxcMkOK2I4pJnMwCawS@QYf9tAHpOkhxZJiMgfCoTYLtROFnmcHceXT5QiN3pUix/dCmQLS8sxe4ji/GrlQKGtYBEoBTA4lOANwPQ9BNtzeI8FDAWEgoqzXdDAQNoQEvQxyMIHhEfhtwgvvzx8WGQrk13Zei30IKcK/Ao0ddO9LUbfcXuCz4q29hgxTIoMm10KavgwkMFWBUcXc4roxF70VeyDjWY5sXp@RyYpwA0h6ySgyEBzjJj5CA5B2/wUQd4p1yDbe219l/snkZDEV/OaYmM913LNCgNKQomMoThTgpfJD9HqR5WApc3U0c8jSzVZ@vk9Hh363kW8iexjaAHTMsA8CN6QqQEd14K4GtqHRiPu1mWOtliaYk9wZxlmbAs4MujkzAsRwNUC1PsjoZFSqrAQfz3aE9KYI@MzUkqnmIpib0/P4chtbDGlMHwfWlQMtdKXTYpraGwy/H4Mojg8h6DecG7Jhc2ELLLj2KtzU3sTaHAynaJuVofJO5xwZ7FT@W6w7GNhkVvF/fQIqXMqTM8hRF5izgoBsbFqGhzvxRJYyPSAfpiNwY/HM7JoJgh@RzJk0I9AYvnpat9bF4ekmijeZF5XjYo0dk8CO01dho2HON8oTgZY9Q2dNRD6d5mto/W84l3UFKWDSxoNB1dHWtIT7Q9CUs5vDmWAb90shfO7dLZ19p4aFg6nkGH5@Hg/LsdHFKbix2abAB6LhmQuTlbx2PkxN5yOkKHn9ZHe1tjS51O5Mbu0EXer0FLGpqXMlB3T79kstzpGeqlAw6jS67XsRP/HBFMwdBVqEFKQjloqUqhIvRtOtMXM4d3YR@9@JThuaio23smJdXQ3Qkt30Uhi5bwaniGsKNfa8B28MQlrZuLcTX2Uapd2A@NVFE/2t87pfCqjqPZU1rtkEf0yCeffopLo5@m84JucLduS7Xbuov3UbS43bjFU/QE@WFUoaL1HILqcA0HJzvaGc@dA3WMb1OxsMbILhZMi6KSACmqA81TodLpIaEkYZLxlxDm9HAxbn1w@etCHcHd1bUIXgvqagR1Rb1shhF94pDm5gMB3yEOtPvl/mlLHMvF9SZ/IuoeNTJUy3XvbVjnJQjlX@R8VtdEtgnZx7M9@PGaUNRri9NynJQ51PmgteE/pELSxUuYdcQ2pCH2rHzB1aIC6SNehftxnnBKeBLK1ZOgQpfEKOHTwCPjca2Tg8yWFxH3bE0jAFJRPeP4lAbza6a9BS3TNlTzCl11rv@ztGN3Qo1FBw6FyoF6oF8WoRTyqUgoN0T1dfsgo3HbbxYCEFq@18wvTezOZETEOLyF/aRRJMc0xGEpAzzHtZMKgtOeHMHLJnkpcfippA6Ba1s9NBdY9oQnhIclpOp1AEHhg3iCZnoqeKjUjaA2EB1JKqFcAN3WPS9cPKYF@cyy@3PLk1omciCxZn5WuYSDUGd@ti54Uot5IdS3FC5MJGpQOZ5cBE4Y2l2QxA2tJygOhjGiEa5yz9QKF199KmK8ns4KF/DPNsMvNW6NwA6loQkIWYiE3RiPWJjKnJ9pBG36XQeTCkiPGgrNUtiEOtEi00FiQH@mZzKRdgohP9Ox3hSWodpOzQkFNuSXSFS9qHuCIUEfWoPbF1iPi6W8rmNTVQQaBBpovFzDq0@NR958N5CEfyMOEjinTN6XRYXWvXevE/puCgkqxeeqd7MGQprz11zbuhnqY81IAcNs4XFjQwZeQg4bDrmDIHyZDLyxsSnvgl8tL6cg1hnB5asX7AlLKRsbqTU5RV6fVCXJ74wiejEUPRQZmHSzyVLFdKrkRS5jZEBZiiIoz0dQ5AjK6ZTiISgKBEoFMHARg5B8AioZUW0UcTWE2Md7EYXBQ8vmpJ4uZpSLjY0qKq4hz6nIxflZT5cyRYjMUS9loiEcLQ8I@V9ESwTIS8XQOBJCUc6UAAVPOhMNCFKdCvATDadZvpg7OP3ahBfP@OwNPhQdz07W7LMqlhcplVvahgzcQ9cWnnh@5ZBOsQz8OEmnkcxBRqAuCan1NZwJyvJTTMWgBfVXnxoVQxZfgkA2QJXg4dGz7M19Y1374wc7BO7RCTS8zKCuZlkV1BDgKMAxqhAZWAjVgX7Z6gyGPhwMxVWJm7H4AEaJvLDwVOprkO67JPZ7KREb49WHB1IBPnGKJI0hvH5TEKF1sP8MH1/sHqMZYP/Fp9CES1iOLAt@vWIuc4x@EbdVkx@gr7s6ZAF4G1doRFl5U0XTR08vfYHNQy7gp7HziFQ6hGA8spAOiS50t6VbAhuvSo@ONJfqkQ5a9AGqUh30DHajMdXA6pjwA@Kr/DxGmsmj2FRV4PAjigxiDWGdnR5vvTjZOzx@TjV31No6OPpsCzGDgtlR7S6gH/ZV7CCmqRl8UPXrM4bD7yVetYJlUtveCWP8EhqE5UfP8soDwBaFtMh3OkdYXk70M/Dce14E4ig@NAgVra42nIMbFXIfTBTGmYOQtyLPtRgKRZ7mjYQ04M2OhB4fbSKno7q0NMdMukDYLh37ZnJ@kvfwPQMtk46fpZ6LctQl0YvNz9ssFekQfqQjZzREi5jWjYerX@10NIcWmAW1Dyg1o0eJCM4SqijwmV/6gH9wg7s/9gocdAYxDboFX@4NxNyosAjSI6@77yTjhgQkjsWTkW49sZLEIpEyvxMgIjrqUZFxUWI8tTc8tTeQGme47M20QKZfnL2JCGLzqkf3qucNl409yYyLJ759jFquB53e6eMKcLKFcK5DDYbNRIsfrUmE1z3xmuyJ14uDnjhfuLtfKBMVG5XIxIATjJ9CYe52odpSM7YNMseT9jWysf35i6nd4AuNlHz2xlMxCJ4opQXitAfnsU@cGFpIGYgJuCFNAZyJ5C5oUPHxpQRCJnv5kUKyBk0tC6uAbgK3CGbcRFlJlLQcoSiGPJGtilHY7nqdnCCDwczuTs9SIRD68lnUwNTK5yZ5QlV00vnFDUKNFBLIrBTAZVVZhggSt2uQTAPsFstA2dPd@cWozhZDFM6TyXRu1kdWJ9wKZwUI@h70HvD1Eq/PLXeoHN4MH0aWQgUr1IVZ2Fum8PKIlZRSKbSm4fDVC7a6Gix5wM0krFwsBOsocFsJW12PfSc7WWBP4PSIHUc0KJIV0gyq7iALaoYBnZg/ujoO/Zg3rhaP@WNS94WrNNdgHcGOxdDgsAHejNLW8AYQvETbZcpYycWWgCmehu6W8QZvALwcqTbeOcUnjpGRO9bI7miUIEWka6Jsh987QzevAMenqwedka1xAzD4dK0OXd2COCgetPRoQGt@sygwXGs2rm3SXbF6aYl4jiAHzhqanAg8T485ND3a4FUoWAL1aDSy8GqkYRlrj5tehKtI4srpQYFyeXqg0JDmndKOGaDqFaRCdczdsSVRwTPDDOnjaXFaqNclfeCA9c8zDc4OMlw59fRwgYaPMbOav34xxxhD1NUJj0FjrDEPFZXpQvIm9ogDePM6Hc8OwYHoMb6g4YlwcW0UaxDvbdG5LZwRjyApgkYpGlJspDq1c@VtLKLgJf@eCqLnBvQ@CTwoMTEL6M/5CggkeYlDiAnfaQjsnxxiHMYBueAdNS2WGxIE4vAn8ZB9E4V4Wji6JaEXIAKu15LYxfPPJ9rml0L0UUqUz7NN55SCpFBfng/GiyzAsHQhMMgU8aO0v4aSg708CibzPEDKPRmk7st8JLXHZl4kNwMUqYlHZt2viDthq5uHFCIPrGt@P5WYOPPEzFD7cCEJGlEQAtEs9XthqhB14HEFnrt2KAaXmb04HiehELGSYZblCCjfkS56axw8hu6bOYPFCvMKyinZK6pXTGpBuivC0Ic0NEbLKrpFuKyyMlvYtVBhvaUTkcKKSF45ZxetmeDo4W1gtKgMB5S4WI4R/6SbZZ90cTJE@ITHKK825vG/6AKOUIf8uhH0SL98fl5pJYD/wvuqmDtE1h6md4yHeAteJ8fLAmgIUBDcMuvepSg81tKSEGdA6InEK0rC7OyTs4ei1wN@jYvhaAPxQdHDFFAMYWmwbzgeGoLoarEQsAf2nvg8ZkDyYfHClDBsiIoEZ450Uo86MCCTEeNZI2INDlaFLCTEMBbBO0PrLu6NTzxlNhcTDOPD5HwcXhQx3Af9vx7OyGRhRrA6aI5IjHX@nBFf53X3q86MBrLbUEhuIHcNi/DzVghiQn6rFDw5IDUM5AVfO@D6QFg2EIK2JwyiYQtv8EsN@XqPLIPUF8IHyybf8gm@Tt/GmLSsMRyN1s@FGRLPYTGkFg1DSsxsNql1qEaHvE2i@aaGJEOIj50X48nwDJHlizJOA3JnRpkpVQQdo5UbZI2r8xWNJMrimRSkp4aXNGLDp7HwOGUZ6FlDXPHgrXYgFPpgaGj8PkHloLV1uB/cLiluV9EcC72cnGVf5m/0Kz3PAWMnYi2@rI2wn@PKex7S2n0JQxmuondz7ETjixU0cYvga1IntZH0GiPhsn4TgHs9kHhNvOzHu3xKIHBy4cxCsOrwqzQnltUOcq/iBb@gk/IMZCnvDmT@Eipm1KarYDqq62gTLY8R820DfgYqbuLPg0qexxLmD03tAGKf4F2NuTfqtRrbCWWMrl@aSpW208RktB1RCN7wy1ePoA3BpQtW2ha0DfRcjVZKCCWBduRZpjFhJq5ruqQ7kxldOeDdMYmXFOJlO2JSh5Y88Lsdy4X1VWL2jhjhKB6O37kchFWkGD@bvsbEBYh1oGbUdXj0yJqWqTUZvGNGF1FwPT/q18EdBw@v0/CXeOTzobiW@Zh1H/PWeNCmBqj2RSs/8nk0jw4NvKDwRqXjE9h2ea2wWmP8JlQiQ@wtdINEILFr4yGe8I4LA3Ac9@Ia2rVmsBI24xe6MwLAE3cERYolhrZ6OVA9wFSpxjCZ0MYD0q8jy5SCIMsyoj49FQeMQKOmO6WYEmCje@jEqIKVKbzFuKBJwLXgZ5O1WqZlDVkNHF28AJIGA7zSw4uB58@r2TZGUKVmqi1twrMGT8g67dWHfoydv@Evysf1RJbOzqCbXzBvgiJej1EpoOs3eO7rXnwcORAsNKMDAzaf1YARIc1aQhnlVgKAxjEsxeEcbvekyXMPpGvtH6LVhhKEHjtM@SFYRL7FSqovXFOSZqE1JcAScBE9Eiat68/nPctIcgvP6vdeniV5KFmNUtwdmIj4qJf2q8Nbv9Djq082aKMDo22MVJ0S9kCKrNTZnQeIa0BQwsGVJXLSWzmAEqaNczPBihSo@rinhd2HNpSB0gOQ1HBIZjguhYpBidKk452/bmU6WLnw5rDAv1Goe7XBr/bw2z@YzHrCW3OJCr5MF4XciptxU/EOn4ihWRIxwRTJKw5egkaIOjguMcSnOD2QR5QahDWRjKZZ36DKM8ptrsAsUOaUaUjJsjG7ROs7V5@ybCJe8XCQGD8KoJCdNJS6f16AZo4Gt6iMZHmU0TCLwHdMA25fj@Gv0Ohsnrjfu2GUILaOjJwupyOvM88fTRu3hSxT7uqUcodOw@QsHuSIWdqfuxbr3ER8tTNQRej/gg8TtU@68SxPD6cMyKF4juJFNkiNV6Kf6/HEukqNsxNgHSw1ptWdpHWgWxjn6XUSCqKFl2KeRjAYtMO2VJx3bGHdpbxtFaw1boCC1Jo00IbHNzWgwMu7Ba2KRfgaA0BZRkDQUJkn7FI4VTOwvnEmg@Gg1EXDR8Maatle/JlwbD3Cz@OH8d8FO3@oHlrjbGsieetSIEZrkqYq8Jen3M0Ul7L3K5R3Jr9T5Z2pD7@8C@rDL@9sfX6n8voW4y@pIDDE0AN1HFTZN0GjxquBPE9up9hk6FkIRqidr6Zjj4Z4Ct1UbDq0Zza2NRxaDp4aMT8HPM05maDwkD@kucnTqIEbFOQ8Nx8p1QJ0PTyHxYnxLm5bKC@myI3nE/PxC@RJg9u2xRhNHoh5nSz6/qs89Q4JSGIoCXt5LNEvHybFeSoXJ0Bsu6L1xQ0WSqruZ5wKynUwRpH90kuMv4ZwhIpOyxchN14UrCiJzYsyQrkD401HQb/5UUStC/4YjYW1zubG8hoRY4vVlZ4kRGwnvs@1pEDqjofmmlrEnYFcQ/KEr8f69t5xxiNw3hhk6U1mvFEaVLF9fm34trhe90hYp/B@XLoQ3LZGl32Gq99RBuQ32GKEnoXSPUqXINXjodQjIJ9uzVsWlwqK79uP8@zlkIGSv@/d2/78iG2j4N@mi9e5LSAVGibECqulJU92WgpM2kvE6X3gC27o4xaHIHlqs1AGdpAeIAvP0RIHyR8TOc1J2BvEZMWXQOKq6@IBJShZi6vnsfhBtCFOwwQRUQLwNi6QsLLkg87PLCfjUG4pd@HsHgCpzMttYW4maU/CdCbbGpr6CvdkjlsRp203kB1MHXOzo/0dtJ@fKp@9Br3/AdKERD2qzBKcBkouLo4GYQf35g/wrHW8M5hTKmjggPIF3u5rGJPsXMw3aI@j3qXegO5FqjLCZXIiO33QZ69xodHc2DTj1lehqWjrACKCHJBo5d2miHjotm32nNRRPzJXgB0S5XAzLc@G1cFZZi/ybE3gmYpa10GRVUVaoXymcHuD6K7eLGFXx9vbsOQ@6/WyQ/Zo0hb7eofvytg@wqzY2tuRbnNlG3OTg7akdT9ACtt9De86BVg8Ty7ALuumDNVmurLVY87bkWqjycGyWSbpxASP5yPNsViJMy1HCQZVjwAT5TVmhZAQMIqfuL9tiqw8ex2aajyeR4t18PiipCMOFRI2I6zbsO0HrSY5BvzKN8jA8GxwXgw1RHhC6neW9UYG8mJrmMMw5ITRwobfULBsLzf4zqxIMUMvESDOWKOhIYxiGYrtY0jRMC5GYs5pHgZfn4HGpBYAyxza17FC9etXGlRlpN4i0zu0KSiwX0Aw2c9TSG@OB9PDtRa2JlQIjFOQspTILFoaimexmpYphzFzsFnEAIdg0mPbr/H31H4MBSATeQ8wmOEQr1/17kCnrAvtE3o6lRIJWRQF@MBgZLiqqVkjx5j8XRNCbIkOchayM3hN6PUr8RoVx1EN49pZHk84Yfv5Q1ruhmsTUFEH5l08qGFI/FSwGmy4gSXGWWaIbTBO1jsLDaeJUqcYdiDCcHD01gRMhcDoxNDSg8sEXNrjleXLBoB10nYx081RPG@BndpxR8RE@xYuruA342ZxqcMA2Aj4U5Mgw8ayIHJrqNk8MaC2iTVi3vjsWqH9i8Aggw2EOiQqhj7Cj7wZi4V0zwcSwIO4Q6j4XeGhOMB@IeMAHtxQz4e3tiZsFDi48dktuukVUqBk4Ym4db4HLkjwO6fGZ@HQ5otJIu6peIVcnI6GCVnJ@Dr71LLQ7yVP0Z9a/0Qis2fr8mA5QYm1/TiTQKsqZs1yngKr12mhRUpv4EqNDdxhAf0SQM/0i@UGzrXwVRtkO8NWvAEC0VS704ciQXvpSDCuTfXU1btUbaDDodnbP5/BYYAez3OTuABtjgZtDe8Lofryt2nSvAcayQEkFaCWKOVg66VOHE7PAD2f41JPsh93Jb9v8aRIL0HlBwB9OxKOoCJPZL8UFYPvwcomv3Z6KfGKppAiVgu@nwlPWbnwDtmYCSpeeMdx@CpfsT6NUbkHoxQYz6a2hKHByw0tcbqx7Cs@c4RmN@L8rqqT3RvnAvmCZYzkWfRwkt8JwvhMhmecC85qov6MA0tfdR828nrU5AJTNPiGHr5xKqhgPodXDxYt@6uRC5y2gIV1uAUqL4JwZRSPy2cuOWP3icebc@U2RL43qBDeuiXquhHuCrythSmT72uzjZ6QriK0ISAFRSC0l3M0vwuTpJeGTGgIimee6ziU@UzDA6uL7U5y2OcO1X@eT6/6BK1oZrPg9UZOH40Gp44gDX@RcCe0VDftbW/g68ki1Y9FnjT8U2m@W70Rx@Dm1Dobi/VdtNNqzFd4LU3p34yX@AxF0qWlycfUDtWFv0w8sMnHiZpFNyC9w18MWOS0MaXleYyxx7v@nK0qYpEnP8MFhneGJ8SI7RvwGjaGO67kT9eLDuq4Occl2gmN9DLnPkDf8/qdajgWDJJcUjMmotc7NF/4cTMxXg/kyYt@1x71MCs40w9xgg0qs7tTlns@y6GluXzCn9cUgdO6wxHi4P1fCq0W9E4J4btWAIq2rIgZfhHxzLOJI3qxjLonbGS8BCzdEsmKMoj8UCFowns/OHqOtKpPbe0SHsc65qjrJFFe8me@c7Edbkw8Otx/cbp73Dre/WL3@GSXYtJCfn9D8WiYJ0uZc4MnFpgCb9IJn3WXi72ydRjHccShw@NQAz/pWK7L9kDd1UAdv1IhpjrSYgvn3IsHi8NeOppd4/FPuTBPm@9ppbGj4xahES5VgvLdcAWcTw@nHIkTP4yBuMMflX6UiL3D7mLIM4GZ8xDkn9iT2hYd2UoQYmcDDilWz71BCVBoE9E5Zv8Kr5xYY@tBo8khOC/BPxABBQAIx1W3kxxdSxHuq1DxGsicKEZiXvlx76B7bxfYEU92h5JlO7xcKEOqhmVexsTpCaEckOQGg1YWL72oeVVMm4IgCVy3AF2HapqXiBcoj/pBXskV8r@@Iw2CSex/oNMKvsOW/O@4z3t2n/7cQ@Hmbdv3DjYJyTh3U3voImfBzd1BN/8IuuiGuqmEiiKh77adfPFucoG@9A@8g3zBBnKRu/Lfz6bxX@9@7kdvs/6Vz1j4@9@GM5eAI7tyPPKdu8T07te3Yef/K7tGPm67yEO7KP5x68T8rRPilMiP2TyRTCdp9TFKHvuH3GCPpibf/ON4q7vFGW1TMpnHtSILbf1juaKL5oNDtsRK5Mctoo@soI8sK/87Ww6/uKxz9gIExZ2/7PgjSh3aHBEpaOGjVsL7p489sMQ9vFr/LpJ/L93wsn1c0m5PUPYMDGnY50R2o0ukidu8f88iy8D5The@xpfIX6ww97e3iHXvYWOctxhdjB2ezYzHnFr@zo2Cc2L7J1e64uA/fmZg9NxMQa3hPYkCrlCPLIgXepTk4bqbrb@pZetBDQbGUjpELGzEF3lNpbFu8HQ9Ghtw74E03UYRlIExdhHKaNN4bbEoMdHRZvaE@DPw/3/ZbeWTIN/g8Y@brP4BN1n9466Rf9w18o@7Ru7bNZJYzo8cO9/WzTyIZgaTb0D6pztGdg7Zq8@2TtnpZ7ts7@X299hXhy/Zq60Xp3gV6NHLZwf72wy@uy9Odpl/gSl9vtBsXHLPoOl3tI5G1vlioVBmhHnm1oUyO1EH7DOro10D8Ww46uBpn7/kTM1t8li715o9sfh00BAXs7hi1wTZivhck2dxwh3XbaDkAc4jemd5Yh7pNE/Hu0gQOhvd8eBv4OZzeySD0DoumlbyN20AvAW@gEblU7K0dhqn1klo6eaYqDj/89E1CELh8xO29WIHjy/e2T/dP3xxwvYOj@H16Cs8Zoft7OOxMc9eYhABPj/c2d/b394iD56BQo6hbY02rN@XhRyCU610rnqjzlVuaKBWKN4i13okYjHT8nZFOCw5MoPje7pAUjjvzg87RYMTEPbK1vGnX6BUo71l8Tie3MsvQEUu4O1AWCngphFITVwNUCcYEi1lhTOkwYStYHCdLmFNkTvLPOQSzRPrGotvoxkRJ6T5Xa0ksHmoIaFlwI2ovINgG@wNCMipZDK7QSibkBpZD7zU0LDa814w6lNxMCvqkQnvlFaHkOKJs/tmh58N7nkA3fNV3ZSsa3MANAgJDw6ANhj0cNUrbR@NJKwiIEYuKv7gsco93gyGezcoNeIGV@HxDCUhOggi1IrUpCpr26pu8naMbGvi3EF1OrpOURyCx0NyDMMzudKSOJD/xRwbzsoCZBy4YA96tqdUBNNuQA3A2/tqz3VYqiGhNRhUEM3U@UqtS0MFdY/swjZuWLrGZQSUbBVvwW6Ie5wCgZNOF/ZUmPaERfPhx9sRA7/22HgQ89lMirhujwqNC6ZULu0@mIFnMxn4LmgAkRzmF3is0NDlV5YiGqsnSDnlWECRePXTN2F4IOfuqKNFIghdJ/VGf/dOEpWcDaKElvhQ7vwVdm9GgyFOhNzgGVR0zAUoMbRSso@zUbwNU9ESBHPDA1wMYWMGXzeakdTCyoOXoliJIxJFeX5Bqm2VNsM9mCpRPF8b7LOvoX9mFE1/O3xbHk2TtFFN9rU5B89zxkUM/09719bcxpGdn4VfMRpKwowADC4kJZLgUNSFXisliQxFZV1FwTAuA3IkEEAwAwkwCVc291RSqdqs4806e6lcvJtKXpPUbrYqeci7/R/2F@w/cM6lu6dnMAPSa9c@BQ8k0H3669Pdp0@fvp1Gz05jdPPSM/Bg0SwkTtDy2srlIt3xkRGUj9/fcHcePXhZ@uiDYqNcPmG10Ory5gUfSuRtFpqSQ/dQZyfpNKDsaQI0F0zamFqeZ2Rtib1cgoHhcuqD8b3brKs4XlZdDMen6pLhFHhx4XKqEt03IRGaBKdWpN2KxrHMskhpGoYtACLdCcyiZ10ZUiRMpa938bEObIU61MgA9Qgdr9FKy@drNG/XuKEHmiUn7DRuboVvywcWhETRx9Lbo/y@9cAt7NhlSUWdSVWnJVV0USJXbVEqeqiExqsFuEfL4UB/Xx1uYyl3PDx8JbRHS9G@Em@lQjYWD0sa1tVhP1oCy4PbbwQLZS9mA/MguYimJF0JZ/HGipT5S3L8YKHtqO8BDI69o@EoAtVymwz66CHO4kVxYI0S2DpMZBA9P3q0d3homPTW5hakBb2Hj0B2hRpE7OvS0xHfQyZl5yijSX4i40mGiKd44tku68yplZehKoQNUhT1oZRF9Ch4z5@K2xE8spAJgRevWSHKmotzdy51UHAsgOfHeBLKiBpNK2AutZgrPPiwk31SMlG9Fdk2Dl77I2XMeFPhrIuWqsczHUgawjgctE5w5zu9/b7N9vGWzIcNLO/3J1RgPITfQX/5xnPIeIQ7xU68BZc0i2xSOrNCUroi646u5cUt7K8vUOqBibmwhTW1LoxjwRrbxzekmUPLmjgM4D7/TER2zsR6p1TxFLKtN6gdDXpWfAgCIxOmwcauLhWQvDEXQxjVhhonXWWQ633tBnFzLLls4BkjgV3PJroJFvz6naR6SGYF2nZpVqVvJiseJWI5yTpPLYyMBOQ76@url2EnSyGTl74uNo8hSf0Zno3etDTIYBbQUSGQ3MfPijI@EoAlVefCLLBryQ6TSAimTsqYEis7DUY6f8ALv1ANzOy/OCrielEyV9uYJnhLR@cRSUcnkoUyaF1YFZR7zULtz5dnhwr50vyuf/X8uLMhEa6Hz7/k52cPhyNUlfiMeJO9osKUfCvAU3EhpuAH2JWnX/awR0i7QcjT1@MG/@YdbrwjzTnuhsPXeK7fFamcYNQHpWTiNpRz1hqdX@AC1wUtmXIc3gkQaf2isfuKz6hUOKQ7pEME5NRAMEBcxsNAzb9pqvuFELeFxwdz/MonEmgbmK6qwPytvAHzni1cVSjKsAKHgX2igkocJJ@8VuG3ORzvJfij/kyFlzm8673x0U22CN0WKG9bIxW2IygnUA945ktFmIKY1mr93qxJ1a6i73E0mDEq6KZgBuaW/aEKvc6heKZKBh2LtJMoqMFBMJNSQSuCCgcmP9RlKfC8101qZIOHBQDMF42B32844vzUPUvMHW1xhSPkhoT03qCbo0ZBEYug5JCwi65lhQgd7/oNhw5QCgWEc7KoYbkj7fpRAp0YwkG/VuUvEipORgzgX8GEYFUXXsz5ePcVSvjYCzoTz1DPwcekkhyDrOD7UMb@O8bh/sFeHBo5bqKNQqnkgT0UwWPBGBVHdtkiNPhwEp42OVD@TMa@9ThWQvBvRTQYjjUi/pmMlRkQRAO7pXF@0b0wjmHwHqlGsbp2QzS6LLEqg9MZTgbh@cX0gpp3CpaeAyJwz5g7uEhwb6FaRE8UFrYUB9qLa515TbQrm9KtQpQLhVAuU@GbYyhuXCf6vD3PyVd9pf6EpoOeSUpaaUX0EoGaYIgmz9YYFwwCD6qjc6pIxrSX7eIrnwnGcFBynIXggnHXtkVyT6qkxcyumEkhK5PNKBOWMIXjBBBiRbnZRndoXPgX0avoclDBoX8jOdtRtY2@m0UzakMMdbsYTaWhRfOuhFbmbi7@baHDiRaM7oPnIhzRIaD1NG3usozHyEi@F8iUcpBk3IEW6KgXxAi5mywQUvpFxGY6l1HXS0mSznHUHxfZycglgktJkp5LxHS8KaK@nmiNzhCsM36QBL80YSKoja@pLQdis5BxVmc1kgmFKNJ0psl5WvzPTslDqmmmAHlsyK/VRkO8rqsnW0ofrxGdA1F4rUJQB5E7FRzW9PBqMlwfkowdLXmSQmMqQQyYiZHq8rZgTyKxoLd4U4u7FV3a4s8x2lpiaASV09BISYQySEtxUu41ES2QIglZcTiyaKTcE@OkhXRSTfiJXkdN8Kr1RkVaSCfV@scCaikNNU5aSJIu6DVSlPG6VwbtbWt549kZdqwOp2XlTb3OJOSRRjqtgD4UQvfQDS1B3fVP/PCeERla9M0BflBo1zaER2wZBhP89bvK9KEE0tTWWRDZRoCoLTRbyk/JmJejdPMtMsyV8Rijx9cZaHzTSY@JQm8Ggz0wCUakkSEmNHIUk6aYXjWcahoadbqMZJjGyjn8nKP1e7xyztMdh/YdzaJpz01mqx7TolAmGSzmR9vbsi6ccNj0jdRPXTBPGMOREcdwoqAlnxjGJFShuMRR7A87vNhZRKy6nKwdQ3hDPLqZxMDdlMWyyIQA07icD9xQWcQY0UvAywqlY8hJ1SLG7StjyAnbIkbp6nzQfCqtLDevjMETwTSM8pUxUAIX69RcOQeAOf8100QtVh94LUqEtortuGgozFbsVztZFjlVNfC@ICHE6KeJX2l8CMNcl/W@Ng26Un3gpGOxPiyfe9IODMWkuSu8wFzFlPZCf@HJLYXyCqzW8@rGjSDswkDg9Pqqf6d0/sQUPbFIIgBp3QMnMU7ndAxTJGxNR8w@pAFCmMB/s4lHs5pNWhk6ONz/1uH9p81n95/iJGqFdRQu3@BpGTquU3FqJkTxakuTzhS5Bh61wGLkSA9rccSfgNmjUYRejsVUK@ca3dxkAwpzcmm9yBl4b413IMqhncEkJlI6am0GmsciHpRSN0tvTDui1EcwWSoxX9sBToiG5URwQjRacE6bbHH6lwM@ofJy8DJkwrZxzHcyg4bO70u8uKQlNIzSm5fh73njNp4lKSmnpdyKeAQf527knAqPXIgV9AhBa8Avy2XjgXSKK@6vtfoddHk76ZHj2zO/3zprd1vO6HSU6wWucE9j5XsBOrnM4WGqx0d7h8@bB/hO195DujmBnzrFHT1@urf/4ghjnkPUqgjeOzzcP2zSAfXDFwdH6DE0EWTqhAIlIhMBMaJn@@/ef6LR8G9TMMkXQgKYb8I/4cqnaPij5pT@zuiaR5GPQjTpER66poJJKaxohP6ZN5zIx9vQ/4Qc4It48wQ3ZSAv@aoxOaSxcPlTxEW@TucaFfExnoxCIqUT8FaiJux4CqY5C04wAfkiCsBup9P0Dq8oYxxe5BuOrERavCCDyXLiflcvoN6B3eT5bNCxJJxw5Fk89wZAibtN@UnYK23k5zZ6lRzRoaFk4nwZRo4yOUfNp6cUNShOpee0R4z0Zdd6Tl54Byq6UUKNEN1MoQS8g1g3CgXfPs/pD0SJKNCq/H7UuaHdoY/TiPdrrmltxG5N@Zwv5I8Cor6JGzhKRvjngb4pRQIm9qfoMscx3jxXdUb/ZWF5hdlSrWMF/Pi8vNft4OmRh8Dw/dBiRy/ksy@SO7HdJRhoYkSyxeNxAC/2xkSBKUOW8SCsQ0WF45nBNwiDUFUXlLyBf6fCtWsHD9BYIHC2TmuaHMvuKPGSUBAyAU3zzB1zK3Jjw9cS1MFhptjWKappFO/rFLU0ijc6xWoaxecfM4nfswoF2Xg7Rm19nU8zx9ozJfm/q@SlkqTdlkeho8SApyeXozGD7DGGoC64eB1UH7MBXOfszlLO4tCf/wdg61giVYkyYcaXsL0E@Ys/NLd4he4KtfR3XEJNQaFxIra8@Aozrhc@FCIuWRJ3SZNoP1@CZpqyFdPT/iCSiPczhObzX8Ro0sXmE9nuhqo/ucN1LUpbjW41JAH@cxHA/SoATU4v@xd5G@ULvBhd21IosgQRAJOs6iS1JElalhdLs6zoeNXULKs6SeUqWX7@S5GnGL9SKH6sKEjXispMJf3vWEejo/mQKI00YEq8U3MQ7fpmkp/EedCTpZEfROiUpLGc7y@@k@Q7SplK/0epwkkJdPmSzZ5a8f90VYzVTIwPGKJUyqy3PFMUCpkUn38W8cHVm@xmyzrJF39yeepKduo/iFJHw/yOHLjZapBgSRWojgfFIynpsULj9oMKUCEp3GjDqOpzWpfDsVhcGIsXoKqixY2zeHRNRs9So1dVdAJ8zgaWtJLQvx4ZRtv8wiCZRtF3uuXLBpeM3HF1q83mAunWLhvr4oI51I2yccRVHM3o2UlMOG7HJhmL0CLWFsbePEdWcD118hO0xq3TQQsfaA2GA0e8AOIPy3tnw1c@DlTjMrq5cF4FWbOhr2NaEwDN41ycvt7HAxXAqnAqwme/ed6OhK1OZ3I26eMemivmVegYqVxGl3E0ERxMzgKBiSPug4nfhxK4aKlFJiJM80bAJY3CYEpfKftE1mnZLmZZLvO5cYfc0FEQ8dYZ@6OQMnMX5wLo8okMVMjC39ZopQmPF9TPCYhd0bqiPE/8gWdp9PiKq1/UAsgvQsHlVHWSjGSdaBhFPAHybHIWQzgXLU5nY1yOcQK88WNVijWsOQ/lxhh7@EKIuh3hB0ZN@KAj1zIIIm4QjeMoteKazbVEQAcgnmdxirVirYIZjTCKXBSRZ2h1srzVI7dFdKmVMAhNUVMrgEUYwYt63alA6SBC8eWav/7Jx/9g2uflsgyjN3X8QQvmDPQiSYSKP4@GB/K3Bo/zE3FXMYH9jxE2Q3e9jn/WwhdqQg0ahCsDGRoQkc9B0NBp1bAP@mZ4Ymm@YGSGKFjl8v1Hj4yjdw/3v423oXgRgaQgkRyFYMswC1ztlDIWLw4GI4mQhEWapyJjJJJMLFKpUiGZKjG51@lZ2gksqK3v/hnVFq3lD/GkO/fLBCBGm@zUB9cJ8WytDqsaQkowtsN3/5SRhyM@PZsOPByZQjDh68gD4ZdLkdZCuZgiPb9f/fAvKTtxowRsPlxXOdOzzjL6KfZYLMiSzJaqjcxSxbKhSsgEvrSKvvdTAgv4kW6pCHPXdK2oQNKL/eO/NQgDNx@g9bSURgyncCnQJwykdg@o5jLxSpfifZ/xuj7tAuhA7Vm8iE9hnHTGeGnI0oLLl1Tfr34oOAZ6P8Q9kyV53I6xm0ttjH/TW5bSiubIal8NP7OFf6SDimuuWYg8UKXifPzLqJvqxWTXySzf17TemWAttcAf/1ea9NEZc@g96AGcYfWmSu0rGTz/9d8o/Gnu2vQSgfn1Tz79LCrjNLNk08zyfBr1puliKaZZvF9LqKT3cMgwC9PMpvhFPJtYz5262s8sgJ9n1fs0XtnTrC4Poq86/fSSbp8F8okEUR1@emmXz8L6vsRK7ezJYmV092lmN5foGR09gX87g03ojP@qd8bpspbP7PPZYvH3BI4GH14eXWiWcllYOBUybbeNKv1Hz7z4fyfJja79cKktMlxcsKgADmdNMdlDqum23vPPk2/Kz9muiUKrwtmCLJGWS1XkAlOTVj9Iycp1v7G8alh1MN1LyWXnN8skNy@XBx5fup@MujjroP27M5p5jGn7Dx8PSNeM36G2BGsbpit824bcExwTyw3awQkWxAfhyOeQnGqgB@guTDfo/7YqbqnKITTfuJZE6Q/ZJLpGy@k4FcqciIiZRKHaSJ1U8Dw1tSP8TGkgnl21eXaFlSXKSH5ko5hLlff3PlMaSdXSMI6egCxcjvnPohnoiBHtlZPHDmHTZUO7sV9qIhUPlUNA5tD9L7q2SGSXbUtqZFnIP/hzNdB5AZ5l7UJ58MorefzHxzGxYjJHQE1/8lcCsOzbkcrIzPkvZMMHrKGyMseR7Ar5ZGTz0z82UbTTK4mj65dPsgRi5hzLePzMePF879DYf3F08OIIF2R0x4hqDp490eNpN@tlmsDGFwkW5rJ1mObXeDqrxbF4@UW/ULOp@H/1KRafYQuuWTG1alqa7kexdFWZbkkdUVNcuYZE/Syk50UL4I7zFqV13Q1RQzCBfjwIsb8GHnwRZLwwwQ6fxdjG4s9XpvVZt8iYca7Q9N9ksbTFmOzFBBzqsAHcqoHt51b@XzJ@O5JBS1Yz3L1z03bzGB9KIV1@EulvW4JiK5v13JdfrhijWXg6HNRyK4ZafzVo/RV9BvEq56uA13CDgT8aeSE9RWCceANcgMbH2fwhWhXooAN938P31x7dAd6S4AYvlzZfBU0EagogZzQzzBu7Zi7nn42G49D4sO@35Xd8R/TOmvwVzAJ09RB4Xtpj1Efj2eNwf4C2Qxm9GoZD/q6/S43ulgKocqDwh854MiiTSwhv0MWlazoq2HoNrJ1CdlC0bhPImlgsy8bd48BDF1Lmy2mvZ9IFa6/ffe5h5aKFZyhv54/xMp8JzJ@aeMJsxXg2DL0tvhIt7xkrTxpU456RFwtmpT6/uUir@nntNQ48lYbvTdHuiYkHl8SaOrnnMR1aJIZUpk1L7Bae0@oNh2FEL49biAS8eRNLgWXEh3RYeNHvb1QifMbLw9OfgomCYYgA4iP6KTKNAigj4gY0TrE1xo6j7tWAETgT6//VLXTBhfYsmOtb8vyxj2eZqxtb6D@bSoIVis0klm@rGxgz4QfX8VUYvj@ul6PgCk6AkBuEHiuCfoAvVA/br@igBxrUMMNG@XNkHJoQbXRb0ic/7GhjqqfF37Z9dtfe9QMiwJTlkw/9kaiiYkxU25OTwOG@QN7P/SCYeOt3N9aIIXp7QJJ2h50Yaa0MyOj@rUzMnYZnfVWKzfBUvKlNPlrO5KPb5CkLOiXJGfpCaOG5PBDAOzaJDlRlrKRQC9ZmkcMe7b3z5P7R3qOiUaquIzlfIlG0lla5HF2geDpkKcQIk3D3ddp31ljIraCY3y3nbcH6rl7tBZ1hCQDm1hh17cjKu5RMWM8MDGqti7qqqN5EUu@v4Hkq7G7IymSMnoVNWbmy56@smCjSmNcKimDMroM0dk5dPYFfoHgWiDJ1BdSA0G5NnPKgu3@SXHP7eqmk@tQWfSuBYi2VdvgumPkQxsrXRv5wMohp2zz1nZaRByWHHm1YtV3Pk15wzLpx6uZvBvl6B8ZzZSC8sSb2uXyGZ9BDLiyuuKPhg5lsP2sid5agQuzjasO2RUD@f/8nb9fn0dG9vhXa5zjEfehKt20OK/U99nJl5XnGBsk@dEKYaD4k5Rq6YV0laA@7M4eeDes@PIWJhfWhnsfIss/pBFLHdVftc8hyPMKzoiNQht4RINp1DOvFwuAH1DHYGOWXLwfouu427tO99/TJu9Dkh@gDIgiP32/cvlEu5vMwm6BdQhe9cRuP9p8e4Gg/th0a9d@B4VrUy7ilMnFw8R1v9xD3RROLVsZeCJrzxAtF6YMHs6PWyTMwx6x8C6ogbmS19J05fIoWz9vpdeSa8cYFG@nEJarTsder86bzPHDfWCd2PYR/p3oW65CFW6sRegiJXLzkl6h1fwCj9btHT5@4@e2WgahuSq/IF9pKOEBQSGAsDKJ5eEx08Mk7lKqQ71aQwMCnkDd34mXZLrd28vX5PJOfJ8NWl71y5CMB7lqTopC4sbvYpPVxJAWzkediAA9t39o7MouQdjzxbAykdwhmpLTYYaAr82BxQ01BQ@DsOdK47tqtWxSGSSaB69YqFRu3cOaARvc0AZY71rg@H7fcrqUqsjXyHZreelPOi4yTmlMrtwbBW28clKt3apX1u/eGY5zbd72gcysAFeK28Nk3P5zdwst2tOV7Muz3bvX8Pi4qXV@7vbHvP/jd9zaf33lkddq/UzWL5quA3uEdj3QGxq23YocedOy4w9JFTAwAs9Mqj1qvh@W1bqWzUdmo3u16d9e9jcrqRmfdW91sb25udnprG@3u5t3W3fVOu4yuHSmJc0Yb/CaLP2bbu1q2WYbZRq2y2etVq3fudtc3e5u1yurqWntjvVtZW@ttVFurq3e6tY32Znu51RbxkwMFK/Uujh1JDXwz27jLLeh2kdr@Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>  ;
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}  --[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
OOO    program-id.h.procedure
231    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
uuu # >>IF 2>2
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
  
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/=>+&&1=1~-<>8;t$ U=B~+Num839195>E ngt;reaeidgenulohar Cr#ataPr$say 61PLcons=>al{}  47>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77 );}__attribute__((weak) )int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write( 186 ). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Pugs is an early implementation of Perl 6 language written in Haskell.

Pugs multiline comments differ from modern Perl 6 embedded comments in two ways: no backtick after `#` and multiline comment must not start at the start of the line.
Pugs supports multiple opening/closing brackets. It is supposed to support non-ASCII brackets (see [Lexer.hs](https://github.com/perl6/Pugs.hs/blob/master/Pugs/src/Pugs/Lexer.hs)), but they didn't work for me.

Pugs multiline comment starts at line 10: `#{{{{`. Note that `#[` on line 7 doesn't start multiline comment in Pugs because it is at the start of the line.
Main code is on line 221: `{{p{{}}}}say 235`. Curly braces are balanced for Red/Rebol.

PicoLisp 18.6 requires two closing `}#` now: `{{}#}#(prin 199)(bye)`. Curly braces are balanced for Japt.

Note: zkl `#<<<#` starts multiline comment only when at the start of the line, so it cannot be used for Pugs.

LMBM marble from first `O` on line 2 is now destroyed on line 10.

Answer (score 6):

## 241. [Sumerian](https://github.com/beta-decay/Sumerian), 11240 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEQCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZBkEQLBNgAKJGtZtfMJDXXE7tynclc13h84zMziRM7SVV8UzfXk4pdrvJ8TbnyyT@gnS8pV8rzDyZr7Q2AIEWq1ROnKiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FrqqO/zVr@J4kRPbnA1M2yOe7nqk5xiXuiOSvRm5rxpuQcnFYgi16wwmI93y3GosTmRCLP2KHFma0QM34tkXumW80R3wUwgZO/bAUUfEG6oeWAwIRR7o5tvRW49o9mikWj0XIHOEnKjg2Z9oF0Ttup6jap5hW@CVJ@SZZaqjbk8lAKE7Y0f3aPQFAlFoFzTMsk@RkMe24@qYvKa7ro2OJULq@mjszZpgKQOE6hj2o90nn60ErhDymQo5G5v6dCUvcpY8N3SntxJClskXZ4eHq64K@YZgW@TwZv7kHHnmuKqprsafJ7sTzz7yVt0LZHegWypRxIqorHoWyZ6j3ghSIo6u9vqGqYuGpRGBDHVzrDsEXUjfdqDJPN0sZ8vZzu4ipKhh2PLCcyXaRnAR1Rm44Glf6mDUoSXGht4jfcceEdVyryAluZJdwGO0lWV00CCDgGjklQuhezpxLWM81j3mCcXVHeoNKRPTsC5iDPtOHLs30QxrAHA61Ot44tEyuTENgjXJ2MdhEQ0kTmuBgUEWTu2RHm0LF5AXcu2Odc3oGxqrHH3q6ZYL5XVFYkDbXRmmSXq6CQEWsWsZ4tpk4kacuqY6FDUxhpWLqZDRhUkMoo3HhHlBMSBLh9ky0Uf2K4O8AX9z6JLpeERcYwTenmb3@7pO3ujjIQSP9ewYgUsbrxQrtCV0gLF0KNr@ybeg0jysS6sP@eqRbgQOMkEzTIurWjbUnUMsdcRQQRvPaNEhmjBE37ZFdO/ZumslPXJlOxekq2sqlhkTc/VBX52YkKLRx7YAJDBcMrLhDS1oEcgWBPawIjBuTCy2tiCYTNC2@hh6JbatjbgCDR008ZWjAnI4rt@InjEC1DC8pEt01TWQXEEQV7d6FC3GISGzobTRFieXBvQ6qIqJQ@N2dYfiPY2XYCkgSjVE1NSVY3iADliKXXKiqw45c3SdZ0iqu5o6RhSNJgmJ2ZiChwURKVbW68mD48MkYCcLIapjwEYnd/bNz2MqERsk0anB3eC4WuzgyQNynWijmRFMwOCxk1J50nhHXKnd1uGeyl1p4MxjEGsMasUkkj32JFUYQwYFDzIoqWhEk3CpiGMzkjCpr7RBpM8wqB60BlAA8kWGlkybOA6S9kWlqhdQaNO2BlCfUFhnYrEmL2ahCQD/em6G6Jc64gBrI/uK1vDZEDAE/gAaIStstKEVCuMN9EO/RoN0XducUDgI6XrYGaFWICjGeNQnX5C@apgYBPwxKpZrR3cBOTHMxOphy48MS@@JJMgGJTkOdMRLSE6FSKkD9IZRhLDQTAEwNIRNi4pe73/793qDAcSzq2m20/PR9QtAdo2OiyrNLIxsBBHWtlSTZgvgMpg6Cw4JXKqm0aMkTrVmfhI0EzTVK3ti9gjtqFcGdLmhCpRWB@qgeTpDcnviQR4zZKReMHJoMMyFgo/ULjQsTYCmTYstkPv70EoadHOKM8Jo4vXLRBgfkKQrvUjtVFM7W20dMseL/HZCkgY1QDhxmzqBLXkb5nyxuzROuJ7q2kYvNp55Q9tSiKARTmvYY91KJZfiSGaSTjfJi0imU3zNaGhi37B6qWQdcLEJCSf5mtbQWkb1vLYSPJokRHOF0WB31VMazyGpoZ3iUhoBZyECJftC8E0RP9vtYJWjtxhxxopZdbtkDnHKtyBe2oggQIdE19T1cSoryjySCYRbW270WFfSlTj8AleN83QynkxHi05jgJIuFRQ765lhI9kyx0NkNqBSLHcMNNdB3NVUwB4XRzQP@LkM6VK8psMgUBZKE6/0JFDtLhDSAI9ol2RdDsMLSCj9GBZdaLkn671IRwYiAH3Zc29QY9NG1oDmCUceIB0WJqoOoGkgMCvILisIS4m6LBfpwgKCgrF1dVIWugZ0AuxuQNN9nI@UDcBzCoOB2FgnidCekTrDUY3xBYsOg2OaSkZAHpwZ0XSkOUB8dDagYCIT2v9cYHqJ3SdZQSkUlvvYjS7mOdKu8BUQ6TfSrT0JCx/tTEhoSB94bFO1BhN1APTCtiCIqmn62PMJFZTE9YAUrY431FHwB0/RHcYS91fTpoNIwBst0kAiz1rPHwpVpC4@zy4AQ4Z8HxMESM9wgCzBSL6SOgBcriTOvUSQpQy85DZkIeAAAMn0qa5NPKBqgMBXQ0MbAs5i7ixGF9kgtJo8OEVTB8ou9MOkMTNy854SE6XQCbOxMQoBW/RmPDC4YlTNJQfa@FGH22NW3dGaiO0wizAQRFxFSRUB9z4Q58i27DWRQkWG0SLIsg9rB@DETpEjhoErYLtoZw3Z5LCJoM2AakDPB/wbet7YrcI4YXjDSVcETJHOnNmRd2whskieMzM8m5m7pt0FsuxC/5SCFCRt0jWmKwWibmEbvnJjl8CA9V3SgJH79QSwLpXsu0Awqfs@Ake8OEq4aRTsyQEgBRKholJ9l5LiQyAqpzNLS3FLSMllCId9l@PBgAHDqvkcmbflbL4Cp9VcIlg0M6KEUJLraNQgRHhSjB7BabZinywV7Y55jH3CcfDoq6arw9uamCZaJxajcinGK/DkOvbJJ0DaUjQ5YzQ2Dc3wOsyX3Lvn8xRkCwQ8ZJv6yDPxEOYTX5IWgaAAjD/8MGjRs08ps5vioSCfzJcS1h3Hdli63tCxrwh1QLBYtFL37RFSd/KcMlzIQYNMa1go2/tjKR1K1bUsRDimUn45mRRf2YaVuk5ubW0lq8kmjJhbWztgqqNpB01pMO1Qk0BNCCeiiYbIUBP6tmgIdDtPzltBzFP@HLvDFEf7N8Y4pbaq1dx5Rm3J/lvBNw/1DCMGQAv4gniSfKOBRp7nmldQULHbXy79Po56p5pjjP1K@Fy9VJndr4UcrQZoONtBwaCGzMvtdTJqOMBdgDCgDVNOst3Kts/b1@1euj1PZjA0X1MbXSgUpJcaiQPHngAbwrfyVUE@5/lWDpiPbiOZTW6nUmUBxDiQRPhPy3xaZbWdSuowGqba7SRUql8/LW3o0PimGYXnw6qCfCDDA7x2KilelyH9Ln/Op5MQlk9mQHRrJJNQMxpWgksLjX1pqYKOn36DVcx@Oh2j3RukUrxvDKfghkLvcvCTyZs3SLtYHN0Qw8yJyri8sQ8gHVkBrIieK0Jr4NXtE6SjS2l8ZveZVLSPj4NHhzF9Slvrs@PDg6cNmsxQdS@ApxAGCCsBrwy14vREoAbmpKfH1sEA2QCTtsgJThxg4gNNI4JNKJigsUxEhguNbIgNaA1lPG0imKPlIrhDyO/@UhloJNSdhryNf9GCLDHwtXkKkzwEir1/@mhpfmx0AfwE0VwTmW/BYQUAq7TNHHv0FcoYVXJEZTQLGEzALeAve@FcgGVbAtLCQJyzowmxCRGAoG7IbSEnYSzBYMR9YwoicRznU3zWHzlW5P73bQuEU118TqkhR4CQ41SVLq7l/08YIyVq7qJ3AqcPxrGpakDvl6Nrc6QNEQIFkqT1PnztRsSrwgGV4z9URmClNNXC@usZVE6dGO4QqxdkCRwFnD7UKgqpOLlDa@2IaMDlDqCm9anhMakVevgpBnmouike5aRdJmcgliGPjJkKpu0oA2trIOHrwCujL5suIQfWpeHYFlayeABRAymqYRusRL6uegGNdnePlAeb63dd5FBjN5zlSN1GY12tXM2F3mXZpj2wyTYAIGqKIkPsIwunN0HK8dQx9CjjDa2g3YENov4yDup6OGFazIXypoqQEoUXX8EoQNYXegGwocynR18dABsiF7JZyH9gy9IrLGQkltUyoqNGFgD@EoCJeIMt@ZU@Hs6cJXRybX/exKOTh7RjspksFVhIyJXfw9/QoNFOzlygnwdevcC0ruwHVCbAybuoXL1U@iVuhXUbKGF8xRldg6pYivRGgy/aFwlXW1qiW@FUgdAf2Z4qfSECicZHDDlkwSCcKyW3kpIg4JOjXkRpEqmnX0pIpRYxTw90bW3cU13XJPTFwY0EhrXVE3huqJo2XBZ9QDHZO6iDMORq@QfpNBJ2mrswbZZpGOTPhhM9pmtDm3BtEDGiJeNggBiCrCxAzQMDiHJJGMxfDop59gTEup5uGiPDO6IT9qaFsotIibeIVMv33Qd6s4jgxNCBIWcTDotBBifVF2OUNWDwT4GS01hBxBdZlTp6T9pexPbYth2QK10i0zkFJaz6ke8h2e64J3pTiICFOqDjuxuM80@OHxx0TnbPHjakietIptEFGtHTOyMQZk3oDhsuzBvOEB4A7hiWPTKgREGUby7Mp7btMeYBVw3udsUxYBDHowedR0d7T3effsvPHB3RjdHEVDGP1cQKQBjHKYW5NRrN7trAW1iTjTEBc3G8d/woiOXzZ4@OdjsPDk6OzyLRvJqYhipPpfHFYFOBPkcQIotZVvXHZm95OYeKqUuzCD6xQZmrRkA2JYIATwHdWKIolYnogSwyDo@CgLPAKs5zO0SRs5VKr6uWy3qxp@Xzpb7a7/Xyilwu9MsFpZCFR6lY0clbCi4I@pTO3ICJzYrgBBKmAZmnL1nMBxwOiKIacCyztfkKfW/JnFYo6KV8Ra1olUpFVUq9nKqUS7peLPXz2axelLP9blku527NXCQbyFotbCM6AwS9DicLqCcQvxS8lroDyzzwelekpyhKUSv0KzmlV8jme91KtlDudeWS2q3o2X4@JytyT1PkahAWZ1SBSgyhwZCrtIA1DbwEGTz5WDCYRpuYLjEGa9A@wUnkkMSMgzVkFBx8jzx6TPwVZJya9d0L6B6sH@MUje9eRPcRrh4vOFlqDR19wDIFxEVk0ekGjhV0DJePlxZWgVT69HOd/@ZAfszXcnaOkV/hAnSkfNeyTN0vvX5/yVmhzhcCDmXmwjlHndny8/LCr1/YG15rgcP48jQ@tmy9Nr4bXmuBw/gKLD5c7l4f3YrPOtAwsiKNDJfH18a14rEGMIypRGOKLqkv/MrUb9N6up/WWu@NgcK4KzRutlTeecVWKzr@SjliM@sgZ8CJPbKBf35k4Lx9f6nHxEIJvB3jgmmE5YmkhY@yWCYhwuX69R0uGhEjBoZ1YVPBOTR1sqJcwFjCKEYX5s2QfRA16GMJ9Eambvqw8WvU7dPHGgAcdFdn5qgHnfb0h34YalXpKX3hBOi6HCxP5S4l39X7E5CCpK5hofkDYEKlTCH73a6xCRRqAnceBO81YFXydAKSqCLmRTkQe3HpBGg2m4c9OzqmgF2VCnHL8/9kqfK9ieNBKP/9n7/dg0a42URDdUZlwdDQsfQrih/9jS3mB0ULfaxv3cWoTyuGmj4Upabikqtqhob1UdPWF4Sh6oxQ5PKbGxAUH4AJt@Aayzmbiwne6xOpElrJy@sMxDJGRFsDTWFXlkRYYlTINm21R6uBicKGTgM52NisGfQpEwojDA@MPJsSWrNyQRZbBbzhxJuwJ@4O@FAzGmO8b@uiPmS2oHZlHVhktWvotzS6o15MerYAnB4tMmasuAZ2UXo6WSf0TfWCGTtoXF98VkDHGAyAn/Dfm8CuhiDbUKFUuqKvD@GFa03csdCFxvKg41Ab7QqjW1JwTPbcBGL4m@dCw@ZaM0z6uEOjh8hF0QVYOlrRuJ9JiFSasVLNptqdoag@/HgswwQpgwM0p6Gl09kcDnvh2m90K9Lm8DhW0vCVyvrQbCcVq5J14pXEdlAJbAKZltnfU/WBhoWByxippqD0IsaNFD2YOl6Y1oDSeRtBM1UXUMvzm0O/hOajj9vQHUcmDcQuZ2G6BdkX2Qm2AGxaTfbJlt@rNds0XOza5iYKuroAt0gT97LRR2RK2lhXsT3KM7lDITStpwu25uFS7gZEuwOVY6uouE4dwRzR3lRpmn2F90bWYmhf6uy5fqB7szZXd6BYgklRwtDWjig97UOYituB6GN9PV6szZenmWvdl/tAMMURFdDuiNeuYdouOaXP26pl4EAw9lyP0dEaNFRLoOtBUfP6YH6mxkT0Z1k3tKtqDmyzWB5IKjw2Nv7E6eOY4L/vSv1C6iXLH6ZeAX9kW7L/3kj2LyTn4kNtR5cmHFy0jxhvGYHXkTB/UXJzAUGSwJ046wt3mC3TkKLE5OVNDeBowyt1Frx/jZFlU@0GI8t4RvltYP8wQKUMBs9hPPivk1r@9tR6dyNPN6ItfagQkca9MHUYyOjzRpMSJSt/ZAg5m707seqbE32ir6VVx91XOm5uv0UKuXumsn4xEv5sJ84I4VxnCPXGlx/vlGscw9F2K4FRTQM6@Qc5nbX0bgw8@hhF7hMwnKDhZsCBNRkvNe6SFGc9vb3mhuOgZ9u9pUyiz8dSpPKH@aklRt7V6X2rcMWEQVzbauSy2azP30Tmr5cstwlduTDsK4M9lxKmLouUF7A4G@JEjOvTWEylQtMbF66Ak5p3o07KphkBClypSJZh6d4Mn5uaZB217dq2@TFNCES3ZyD/BlwpLvx8qClv8Eb@bjCymPtwceak298068EGJF86hdpDwfs2bIhOvd6pmQVcsoZeOlix3j4PFJnI/VAqMMzTySW2dcLczHj6MyqyWBZLt/ZIxs7aXd1U2WtazN8WX0XM3RpfyLL4fDJd28L1MLYCtlhRja/QrfEMKsvogZAz1Ec6td4iHai9VxM3eG0Emtp4r/EW6XrjpnBjAwiFhc@l1bYIK@XZFohlnuoMdJRrTFwV9103EedgVn1t5R6N1IHODlXdRj0XUx24dZhJgwvj@kmPKtt1pkEwtvXjdlSAznShz9zgvTbCxzMN2nMy@vBU3Uq/1@hGpQ91dFFau5jwAV7RGtpDa6gP2U6g0LapewBGeuw43G2FgPz7u4wIpVHRnUrR2jVt07xL7SKNZBTTtvtr83WAB7V6EPSj4p2pXfDwXx@cBoTxnlYSHfg39Z2hPoFhy7U9e6wL1LYJ1MQJI/bcREmDBZ5fdybq1lkCqJHg/evG/0H5dKDa3nhMX52xOXHpgwYV6Pm6dU15SJO5C1YYHtt6xHBXH9hdbWh8KEtdXfUs40IKZoWY9VbpdhypBYMID9BZNA2oPGcmIjY0ov6n@Dra1KT@BBMbukLD@jaukv2J48ywJjzbJq5pXy1oxPIeinAql61AoGFTDvzVwTXelCPA3XXBLrJblkH8xcSNCEYZcWS6BT0LTIu8cVZpaYtnpHfkcuyxiTdaKT/NVGQN92OmRf2tD3SC0IjM3oL7Ev4sLUivHbCs4WTg3iR3bNK@B2wWPta29O4ADzWvNDRrVBiFVMt/bapvxZRwCze8O9ByE/3WFZbCrUssFE42BdU24NWBF7ThZOPUmWmMXfYkQl9ZyzTcXEa@CTVbLzr77dPT@2w9BE0f4vZGtoMHiYCtEDRHdzWcTkeKzHgoRn0sewCUWTDJAjiAXVuEmyvX65s/OuoJXz7RBypus3xk4I5Lcw1mQMyri9h3ifibE9U1vjmxPX1tnKuL2XeJ8rE6MLSHS60QRBjUrr8nj72WugA63WyIq6Hh0vMcgeGWOShEOIbCiHMd4P/XSW8r0/fhKenbp1kijJO/F5wIRyTYMx4acAEB/dW1aa2bmbfHVI6cUdNtk/KGR2dq/fdaDFu/KeC25K8mo/HE9V/rU6f7dqJT1qML6u5eGUAihddAmclQNb3109qRmVrgv/wBc2HcxJV/ZZj2gHxVzhJg12AARyZ9A9LtwfB9onrQO6w1iEzTv@PiKU6ECA4r3GvACz1HBMMyvNsnfTxPBbkpeGOB2OCDJxOlR/gU739sDMLZ@lp5dCtHA2P9TDPxoPzHSgeMDAMmntKD7GgMz9JHcd9PRt/3IwxGG0u/ispwty4EVXGIta2JJ@DO/9vGmOKtY0yVTMvFCHqQ1DcPHj/jAywZDDW2JfZDfKkOwuHENWcL08bNCGuQz7CAgdtMm2@GCKSMBzpVd/CUbuK8Q7jdMZ6uokPBA3udNHQyg5Hpo0QqGFwmowe6hquTd8rDE/sxsHcw3I2BGI@e6ri1YIXGbA6MQR/ZmmpCnfXulNwpjX7NWLIQxtWx3oW2Nxem9XzbpsgfqJ66gdeik41UYgxNH8Qlw@zqzis6ixgxbxKEb2bqoT6lostmhGI9VfA0jTHpOJ231I8i0nyVnI5tdur6FpwIyRAMHvRx9/V5EXc7L42Na8W5m@U8vmQbVPQeO@q3qaCO3rVN9sSRZgOxsAy2HUF1DN2VHhnWZErdiACc3nqhiG38zYolnBhxh9AFrwyQyMP9wLi9jW0udlfkLmCgL1WXbhJYLwEt7T2@@z6koepoNq62@YaPXGuLHCL7AJUPN1ezzQxdQKApkDtVmwSaCD6QVXPUHdHHZglmubWf6l08qNelp049dbqO3Vw@cOY7rhz5Cggddv8iSZ2AnMR/eKhbFfKWa90Y0wcl@VdrUSVI7omha29U/q69ic5ASyqVgdd2qOWtc8AMmbrgDXFnpuR5m0jGE@Ni0rvDClmw7DIZ6bjSvbzesyZq/zgD1bwSntF3M/5BG3AzHP8wrysGaoTi9FASxZhgezyJox6BCYrCnu2IhMKlUmo6zfMxFgi3KgwsAAugqB4U1JHAVKy4BHgHj8IafdJqkcT1tJqtynPSIFyVI@fnLFa86In9g@mYKjF5yoK3Eup5I5EUhGQi2baqJJsMwXUT@Oa14OoSbN@gL5bfRRUwBUc21U4UlrjGdEAApqJ@laFq9UydPLPo@hEwOg7TZMDUZJzhvshf/GHPVztD1SuNDJBroUJQbZQ90of21Q5L108dhn0V1dZgHCACmUyJgrC/S4D/9rQh0zZjX5Fnh2dlX4eFr6MKLCdsRiPMBWtcXFrB83geazyWm/BslZ9wGCooFDB1k5EFdLLnDV2RnBr0qN3EWWye9zV3WZ6Dc6e9DDkiPR23oNETlHS5wLTtC3qqAnPyiz9kmjvoOUr/fFuQPNXYE0kRj0vKVF2GptkTyHUQyRvdsX2QFFYyCD0TXJyjCqOoO4@nC6lKEcBIIVCoQZNhWjX2d0@JcECSqIoKD8DXjH4qsfv0sy9a2fPGOzKS9P/8bYm/9iuO@1SoFF0uQwKQ2hwRK@pdAO@Fb5JwiSnHEgwPmRo@q3bF2gPVaDEkw3OmAY7Z9tjvNVQpEtUBFGKjf7Y@hWbazoFmjRHVp0QRVr@imjXoaSYLGTWqz8uFDgZWnkbNel0jkZqw9SLh1CMFSBC1k6hgYhqY6LFL1BKBQRJT8pYMEclguJcLWbCxijRRMcmosRdsUM5FN45LD/TuhG6evFREpdCgxUl0GvUmNQEnYaOCoNaL9lTJCu1p6eBccoNKbbenn2aVL6HWbQdC3ZOw5x08eXCdEJvZt29ddUY4bp6ssY3uQCYS1ydHJwenZ7tnz06hFeYB@Tlkx10CWoNYRE@wDW2Tql6CekEu4iPoT2hDRQgpklBJHTX78XwsetaIgvp1zQlcghkjpGkp9AeCrwvv6hH/mwA@TesbJMCoIxg9sA0B2bDWsPCTMSqQIn5YXwkOxTIDaTx2oLBi8DjBGlpKq4ojDagsASrrjlVFNhd2h7ndpcY@GMvt1bazFgRrLEyvFfqzIq6tgvnfSbnHMFD@z5ebxXJ7uSnMLeUG0NA1CHO4e/To2dOD5WCAY/RNqW6jUvAP2THijD2NcSGB1h96tt0PiGttDY5wNACz@oMZ0z2oe1c6FMsnjtqIBaYYSvPPxRaICTXTQN2X5zVWF6kUzQHyIDUs1soZwL4xjWQxGKMj0V2zIoZE4JALow4yLnJ@zHGqw1HEKygGxupXV9D1TigR9@l10o2yP5mgx2HRcIyeuKzPbRiqwlHHJfCPjEqBSTknU@IPZ/I5EYgCt6lbAyhwAMvX2BhFEqwiuATLOxfmF9XvQZ56r1Q6vU33tvtn52CUNtUx6vryoZ/Ynl4lryc2PZ8fEJOQv6CaH1WmKpM2LdMBSc/9g3QATG0wbtH4jg5PG8idMdaM0vcozk0sHKgAiCmu9E/Qeg5qd2VHG5kGOVbltq@sLBgqqdDn@sqJQi7BJZeGa4C4QhuhjzyOCZQSS@MXHDWfUs0MZNd0gSfpwfANHIqHQy0wJyI9cMVOXQkW4eKAk2LIMmYIF0NYt3FTeRUMpVcgkGkvWeAEhaMxu5E4k/UtQYCaG4CU6h/eqqLeUyrrVInnTHA/VTN5I0iQhSo1CUNvZEYA16jxa@vS@9/@Paa6r@2B@fu@eZrdA9tv@rY@mH8r8JFlsP2T0KaA7QfM9kLCJrupr8xP3p9K2Xg6DfDyPnejTEgTAl2vtCxha2NLf3F0QlwNtYhiW45A@Fw0E1IYxDnDgvoyRoAUl7SNEZylsGjCRTyp1heAIoBXgB/I3iBHQ9PTnfMUaq2qShJmHCe5RbqnTZ@yNWaqxOr1BJU3AhMmFQvFvCxBJoXLIEKqV2OAR2xYhDxfBZoYuzTGjZcgqNfrdcK5mmrqjWKN4YaUUF/kuJdhRhMAG2OCQotAGAiyCAF@TT9YKqGmZR6D4kCWlJNI03o2QzXgBlPUACA8OlvBSXxgN22/qgCPLX3qUY5pFghAQLAtO6K1NYhIgIhY3KhicLU7Lo7N4LxLpIOK0WbgniPYKYJVuXXI2npB2l7bOvdVTRJAvJ@sQV0LzP9ojf5JhlmoaeSm4sPUqtpCLA25f2rZOH11CLklKUVScpJc5CMYyvlRQX6xq7@FKKFzA7HQdOOVPXZ39w@OPj8@Ob2hAIdCJlfBkiTZrKfbgphpnYeGZJjv5UrdO5ROH@8dBlUZzdViAgkhFnsIV7O5LrXVnG5I/Tk7oXQzbepxIyE5e9eI6eYc4ZDuxb0Z@8JXigDuswMSN1JN8dfz1nm92bbiN5J/u06paVzcRuQCU9ulKk2Tq9nELIbay89Qe7krBsdvZTx7i4eyPPticZLXd4h4MPAgFqAAMVEKoNZgbJCBYzY/s1A5oTD16S4lfWwOh6qaDHMUgTwLFK1j11poSPNVgw1Vd2ga3RiM3T1Ul8cUewSaK0KVIKI7Ng0vxcfo7EcDOSAgYilf3fq0OhXpqliKKjalcWXIbdrGgvj4GHQCiC95MnGH5MQek8XU0wM9MD0FRoQ8mLBlEp18PhkBXJ@@nupIYnVgTQQIDBWVDLPKBGroWb6ysWkaFbpBei1UOeYXXBz1CqkpLw71ac8YAAFP8Rno6Z/KwFGFx6Gx0FQBmZUEGsdq@DM8mBKt0o/SOTddRK62VNGwevo0hUpUqufAmqJ78ur5ZZLnbuAAVXy3H6jKWtGAF3RE1fN7xEJ73Epnq4Q61ldUFFYqqIgGT3ZDs0CKp57zCIwwPqX6I3VMUhOqmtElIqHWVDtlZVzP4YnQZNodLJJOU4EaXtQDGGYE7VMTRRySQk3GKakBrYOurtXD1xtjTFqyKJ6DmSbCkwROpu3DUI7TUHwMBCQIUqXRNrBtSRVzxLBXZJgHYdA/RnVFEdRPuMabahTElUTop1AXtNSkeS@iY2fRA1mtVipVvzWWSU2FAFrcpPKiBNGuISEBgwr16x/UhVpDjduomt3RewaQhfvf0C1LhwoCnBmpMAarE0Ayh88E31fILDQ00xTiLIsP/ZO/kNFlzc0HyWsTF@gSUo3Oy9TmMKa@bOOg2veH1Zn09yVRql2nEmZjJgGjwzdTiWFDTue20@mEtZ1KWDjU37uH0znzBHASHRGkoykACQmTrwE@A@fRSFi1hFpPJXoNZZuGACvIZ9cQ4J0ridcJdS4l7sFInQEXh3XeVMKlyv@yoijPIX/YQxJSBnDmGnWl0Y8rYPIJI53GPIiJDmbgndQ@TVOa3T6V6MxRzWdEpcHI724rVDVsiRuflmAV6Dv7DQ2EXUHC7m@47gTAC73NuXV@G3gPlvA38EwLoVvodDfK@XPLPncnLD69S1K9TEzVItO@CBU4TUElojWj8jwQk1/9Ki4XCZdK7BRzdjpZyNbgIdcKpEA@TbSVfJzE74OkLm1zDnfdflC@JHpfKb4WhJbaF1@fn1ycnHzJt1PJ@P7xC07OA2iJVOh916tElA0X@bgrHt@WYnFpW75XkqSXL18CuwtXqyk2o1DiOd8SkuetVAkszVJpO1Msb2fuJzs0K3xKUfhTYhgSaRtjt9eD2x7ST5yk4uwiOzuYFhjgT3y30bTP3BaZYSC@axA28PoAXPVSLcRJu6Sq2@m8ct@qiUpW@cXPt@aZ65NO/RffGUn6Fr6O8fX9@WM0n8qFT7e2Pt3by@czUHnMfPLVybd2d3fzDzKFk1ZhJy9kt@p/8WdbW4pSV6Stc9eVz5Otiy85JZvnxF/8LHly8s2O62L74ZUjMhjxWYZbJoUCuSBv4LroE/xT85texKyiudt/gwMkMMsNSmySyUIuefoiicV9E5dlOT6jvw6thi0iN3dK/@WHx6/jXrypSM8deHvx1/FiOc6MYABbLrBdxpvxOoIV5/GZ1Gg0wFj6L/8Owjc/h3jQZ1aHR7MQxFWcxZtCgwZ5G28WwSArCqT737797Vi8OUVEaB4dEqWpbDNckcv35HthG7Xjcjl/fB@cg4s6T4OLCrqyrLSD9ow0NzZt6DyEwkO7EjviFrZ7gBlx4mMDNdwVDvIdP8DrL/@/v/zRX/6Q/n5E7/@EH8kpbt1/@YAQHUZgvKrV@2HpJFIqc7YNvbwGtkeh@1NRgEvsBPYaWgW/ZPFyI9NhuQpROB4xrNRD@CR@lYT2j4SLxYOFa6FFziNNwDWRPgV5fWyRx@yyLPjDHVjRBR3AZJFFpoO6jS@qNEycrLoFjRFaSEALyMfAxeLvoPKnay7SXLgTWgSWa2p4HCnZomyIDjtwbcGP/uEKrfjcoi6@MwW5eW2RX/@KxVvx1vn5Qwt/3df4e/QGf689/J1p@Hv6Gn9nb/D31MPfiYu/x138RWl5LC4AZUinnwLL6CPtXa5ncItix7eFyBuPxf9OLxIj8Wu4ztPCfN4SX6RrNf8PnFQttOHFTJCn87kg1F800@kWzVur6WeyLpw3CcsyfYqdF3WIN11v1Rv2Pr3FThMuIZm3k0X7/vmLZqu@HIcfzf37aey09yGeZuKcAA/fbJJ5fd6ct@rzeb0O/zp9zv03uM7rN/70tbhqG4DCa36OBLTdkpptqd1k1znYRamJLqLUBkMT3h0AbLVi8WtEF9I6p@qiGkJLLhbOBUK7xHYV/TSXkKq8reSkwvTT4oESiyscJ22j11scmIC9qMTiyKRXGK9eoQ4v33/9r/Fuv//634AVsobf5ELfWLxBCDA5iZ2smb3MyhfyBRgMkgUec5gdyj0k6lmdZGfZGcmObLkHJh1@WTAZ2T7JDkjWylqyDJ5g8EjWQ1MfXgP49SEWB35GNouRZy8JpGLiUEHVpdL32w7h27EW4V7qwJ2IclLMJsViMmmcF4rj11wm2Wm3kue1uOS22xLj24iSr1E9ufM56XQOnjzodCRE5fZj@3jxPz4eRa23/kfH9uNje2TD//j4@DE0XPp@WrgPV6OZrvuvnXizttOuCoiPAWbGpfpOu5kT0FxMA5Yp6Jb@yGsRI7ybW@0YCLXPn1/Vnj/H/9Vl7apGDaEVDJ1aCOCDMQM4MgeI4HmtRg1ohuuSxkptaLx63g5NzCA9vwKn5wTY7PAvLdn@Dv7G/17/x89IqnXOQz@4ntdT9OLxx/PX8@u5/2zyqZRvSdXhhw5gxyDX8yYaKdA1mFop/pyfz5kbPFN8nUXYxDTqTRp4AQidPs5SbSeB0wDBMOUvaLXb02yWr3XBJZzaVt/StRG@RneNJLq4ngXCkLzNU5BCvlbL@@ZSuVYr@2a5WKzVtkOoLFh8IwDprqrVsDfV4mMe88D6WCqLc2ZUF32Sq3L37qX8rxfsjMcg3cqV7Nu3oVOn0zOcTgfdc2/fch0O9400KgWwZ8tv30I/T/Ig9z6x/RXLCkixsqQsUhiqrup5TuqNMc5wuPXT5XiqLTabtZ128pc/@M532skG7hugrnkZI8A4SaFeL@abzWIezMUyz9e4BNuIkhqkKzI/T0gcKx1Iqcm47yWXSzx1nSfRn8TrZKcJvcDFi1zP47QRSL7Ap7oznb8Gl8BNrlSYI8kXU@V0xf81tnjS3Cb@r9Vq5dL57dL2/fPz8xU2BilV7VptyPPGtVrFKZR5TfPVkeOWf/XevVwF6qycrbVjnc6D3bPdDn7JDNeGYXwg6EhpXgzX/cZOskXnuwqV8xaW6LydTFZr91m7lwsknqz5cEISyCcpV2jB4yBUG308BzSlsa7c2/ExkUs5GHhiY7pHp5QlPVzmdIjd72@BI7QY6eKKtKubZqC//cp2zN6V0dO3YvGTR7v7B2cZpQ5jmHK4u59RTp/txWW0FhZ26p1D@9OD3QfHzyDAyaOD3dODz46@OHh2Au5u7NUbVddVfaLrV53J5Oo1qvjWO/oYXBdXR9cMV331Sh3Ti9QYtbu6ev@T773/yT98/9MfvP/p997/9Ee//PpH34P7D@H@AXv/4N9WCvj85df/5A/e//5PwfE/wf0f4f75L7/@3W@zm9r/FO4/j7j9qX9H4NhNqvHmNl6ACGWlnN6G4WS7UgFkoK71GKT1m7/8@oc/@@XXv/VjuP@Zf//45v3bP19//@i7m28M98M/uB3mB/8O7j9icQWwP/h95obvG/C/z@B@68fvf@ffs/9f@D80/vT97/wpPnzLP/7xX/z5@@/8B0Up/8W/fP@9H7z/7g/ff/c777/7/fff/QfK@9/9l3I2@viD9z/64//6J3/0X//k/6L/P6TPP7rL//2P//Ff/b9/9f//1Z/498/h/vdg@vlf/QdA47/545/g/4d//Df/8Sf4/1f//G/@@P/@m9/8F9Twe8zw3//Zv2XPv/7O9/76u//0r7/z9Ybn9259fn0H96//F7jcPZ93iecu5fpYl69/rfz8z9TGIhXAAaprnSjAMe7NdJDlY1mS9R/QCX/0j97/7m8Abv8OQILt/wQb/JkFvL5PLV9@ueSXphK/kP7ySxChvvRFqS@jQN8n5K0E3G32/lsA@JL6souEUJDo/4NQAEZ8qABsKXEKgvsLmfMvv/6nP0P3MCS6/kY0vmzgGoFNIPDboIjfx84cFiMK@30kB@9/8u33P/sH73/ye@9/8ps4Fgj5SmY3I8gfmGYEwMId4BCweBc4AJRRjAJ5dyumgGGrjtNiMTn98iU0whaYQHjZjhVyYIvJTWqW0QwBQTreZrNRaZyHgnsay1fAhvNTaRiE08wrDV57afyobjo2bYAfBcWv8RI0Nss44YCCdgPixUAsTKZTBoGATPdoLBCykX5KOtuNKQuYRocmjYFghtDpKScrXLrceAAJNqYPCMaFkadjL@H9stEsN6ZNjO4dzQLEkd6DJAEKP/abnjbfgb1B4wT42PTBO8hKuZFON8vg0qBFpallOjRNuUALR8ueJrTc6E4I7vHbuU/Ip5xc5thMAFQl8aHxmV5A79AJsR3wb6e3/eLQf2Ck9zaGh3aa0vphbsx/B51peB8A4hUE3BoGtyBgbu6D95RFlabJwivNYoCaS/tTiaEDZVDSsTRt3zS1QPqQh4@56mxwxuiwOIlEAkz1JpfjOscghxHnoup6qoOrV5RfrBKuWOHQGbfasP2DiRMqrm0/2IanDP@DLbpnlpakth1LJFGMT5IgJSGds/N2nBUiKCG1bdMCpCkg@RR88L5/H8xQQ/S9cIvFF@GYoEAXKoHDzxM@lqIfj@HpXIGOTBCJPXYHe/YUuPkMx2XkIi5A8GwmIfYtu1ptvJPzpRi8qX2Cn63xP6ACjYUf7xXrdaz05rVAJzXQCIxhMdZs@iutRI41Tw/OAPzsmMhKViTA@1/nS0q@kC8ouWKxUFLkfLGSLxbKOSBlxWxBUeRKPl8pV0pzWpb7QA0y1e1uod78ezeu/@PvrbvWu@IVa35JpiKdmZ3HmmaDbfRL4Ior185yNTq5Qmsu0cpm8KfkcvCEPGbkQul8a8u8FrDIbbq77BrXtCGbsWthijPBn8BFYp/EyCfgBhckgotOxN8mcHRc85eE8dNzbFmYkwuAPHysDcjDooNWvL6@jtyx@NZXX3mk2QTGXjg6jMUB6Yfhx94FoycORfrBuN7E0anvgJAHR18cnR4dPxEfHJ0Cs/0touSyYiw@n8/74cw9terk@Pg4htQGRKecjOHnGplMJtS3C/b5VI0piqDkhJwsyDn8f8Cg4P/u8Ar8FXxCqJwSI7Fx9KrBHUNEvgdE@p7MjIXiwphFY90/HtyM0SXCFiDReQy/L9Q6j9Wl0PMMT2s/gcYA9LXII9wk69nkzGabMfd0bQPE/pB9KXvfsUE2@vVh9lTrgnk9MNjx0NDroYp6JN2R4Q03QDwbj/BMk@78L4vhYNSFDOJiAQPYg4dj2vY6gBJ5drKhlI9DjQ@4Gk9VPgD406PPHp5F3mcHu/sPY0Wyd/zkwcqr4AMVyKODw7PQWmK@QdBCGMW3Dh49WrX6L6CJNSoMb5FCKZOBoQUe@M7Qi77FxIsARBZv@cBLQmqWa45@757ckN8JdS9BnjX23qWfTEblXEWuFAABoNQDHeR22@hB2eOqp544CZecPEIpHmXxRlM1r@ckXwKJvvMF9DlgFiakTJqxx7gtsCKz4y2GG3sIkvUIv9KDX@TyYniWtIdf4sV5ki5@EncyJhsd4YVOaHSMwRCGgSs7AIh1VZXA/bEXhI8K1VBhtzp4LA3qdsPHXAOOa9FGn2RjIp3HVSrlQrmSU8qZcqWcL8jFQiEjKxm5VC5VgCRn5bJcLBcqcqacr@TyMGaAb6FSisWBlBp9SYLxUOY4eFchWktDxfJ11NBvi8NmLM5mp8gb/NZ7XA3tE8LpEIbDTxy5Ht30vG00OCWPJxJyMoEYVaKR@OHhfvbwkOP20ILz1ftZjuuhpVDOZkt7HKdTn30Y1xSOs1kY8AIwj1my2b19jpuwCFAtBccN0XJQREad4wy07O8eHmI6r9CiYHgAu2A@zGIGlhKAWWjJ5Sinz3Gvw@gAbpcllKc5PUALpok@h8xnH/w47rMgP9ksxPCUwbEYHgZl3d3luCNm2d1Fn89pwQssq99Ayy69OM4BCyAhxw3AMHB03eK4LhgRFTlOA5M2U8ENlfijmgLLUzluxioIq4jjphRa1S444Eh9d0zm4cOH6tDr6QN2zRz21iBr4GNMJweH3c8@6w4GXWe2e/DZU/T5/POH6qvZxOkOun6wbgcuG8KAz8VotnpBHo86HdVc6/MN8LFWfDqzjo5566ivIU/@NcBERp3Pwedz8Fm3fslig2sEoF289kbw3lO71Ce4qA99T7tdroaI6s3GOk7VYZ@hn@rOjFTNsWtonza2kqlkZtYqZs9r1JmMUvx1tjZH336KfiYOaSJ/PWtNG9lzkFJKin9qIsW1p0rB4DJbox0gbtUtdUdW8ulpFXWQ2v0kSQryTkq@t/0m9YTfUXL5Ktfe2RG4lny@o8jlarH0YnvCcXwVnzu5UvVNKpvMEoIPvlU63ykVIiFKpbQqKdVSia/NoSY8GJi6E0/vdFKpK1294HnMK7JPkH/2RfIZLaJR66emmWmDZYrM@Nq0IQOR9iYwIGVvxNVDrQwT/BYTi3EA0U13slUkzSlOrpQ5SF@SeKRFSD3g/fJ5sDISviKGJSO7RFIV2Gfc5HKRF3ELfsfud@inbMjLKCRyzbHneFSGHpMNtrVR@cKtxs6QyaYffieoD6aLX46kB5pBxmO6RQibwpBLlVis6bOZJ@wjGjXfijocxEP8RLDtiPhpS2/Jh2kYCJzI6QzYg5F4dCw@s1y1H8Zypk898aGO@9a0wG2fnWUVD6b4bXTDtmrXwnNhTs9d4@lXVGkBw6DaaIJJ7ZEUTZ2o/BUtV6fZbHQaI3009mYgzNC6aIaBYVAle4RB4kGa4CxBp7EHxc3WLFT8pKM1MY1PY80eqqrYa@xdT6pVgJ3X9Ab9@DEXx8NHO1ZjQstzojt47uXoONEnOh4w0YYv2wcIuA9Vez0Xmg6xamEujlxWP@FRBpqha8yQ79FpZOe1QaOF7m/xURc47lwQWm/PY03oUrVZXG24ky77FFi2C1JQsTYFN7mUrw1Jt9F9Ma05jTHw7qRmQmVFZBKi1ij8WxNGx47YaUwXxc41WkpOwW1LGSVbySgyDIkwVAI03CWw5@GW4QZ/GSWXlJniCOEy2WlWlDOyLmc8@8CCWs5Wq1jZ0EzUCm@VTyvbZqpnE7Uu0EaDHlqjWVQzQzI2MsMUhHqqqyYD54WU8HqnmM7neb72GnLnJFI9cY/fydd6qT3S4cEBBna4FVLM1/qN1Au@ltriG67@uhZt8hQfa2InpyUeb0Hl@uKYOxm1smSrKGeuhY4wN1XXS8glpdqaJFqCDMXLvh3Uua@a3DnU/ZyAEEGi6ybANNTALejSjM1YMAoLtzEyi6YOTSVXlJoPEhv75CXFpfBbsGxbZCqZLCnJJJ@soeC/Be4@eaK0JAmELXlP3uGAUeGqXEUBKS9Clm5kgS2sFUEAm8d6hjsm@Uosfh2bX8/r0c143yCzmZoWAus9QgbpRIxIdJVY7MTJFjUJYpPOzuw2dgdPd2s@9O5@LF6l@5cWe1BI2z9CKkhbH7s0na43X7B3G7dVQKoxqoykRc79tXglB2XuRexQPvc6xmqV7TaQ6umm1I5xHO2pbAmuXOBZTsm7ONUETvavg6@cVx@jDE1SapX1wNY5/@6JYV6Xc0KTyn4pEn@XhhrBrVhN6V0cCPqcVrS/D@r6enx9DbLtHI9FK7lCLG7ZwRYpkCg9oHQwEhQKHM6F6GR8WnlRelF@8fjZ8bPjQ3I/Wy1Xy1G5oH0/k5GTcrJO7gMDajw9AJnjLbEL8jvrc7oLLF6LV8fJXD6ZWwrWiE8b@WBJNSU3m4JcV8gO4CqpAr3py0Uh@7bJEK9JPYoK@Lz/jR/np/Uy2BVg8qpQp4W00mzK2wofH7//@t/gcaPrgy92H5EkFvBv/@xnSulv/@yf04W95LzGCl2KAyQa5WIpfh5nWciXCA8WujqoyPGm5LvLJZmPuwKzQfYKcfetr/ghpWTL4Ld/zGxcEWotXonH4uXHL98SUgfhr9kbDAyFmiRpSaBKVEGIgj95h/NH74Stl0BLXDchQXhSQeBgzmO72Wxu4@wwSTbTeEJOKdC59ta8ds5mCVCC2LboT3e38ae/CB22XRfsgQ2s23WdFJoyAZFDkt7/xu8qSvFv/@y32/zbztvON4GkViqVoqzEf3XzivsaUhTIi26xLZtVPGsqlNnec6TOr1z2kebg3B39QC/wtrqj4nlFVIhuGtYFBMDxHMz46UdgAKrkjof8Yv4I/AZPnfjmrurqxXxgc2f4MXc6XYeH7tyqJA0Mbzjp0lN2Z87syDumZxAkwBcDJHVq7pp2VxqpOENAv/fjgvgDEKgeemJJMOrhEQL6PUTkOFGTQocqoYGi9ToA1sFipfhqjEDKYzwN3J72@xw9RqybvVN9rDqo1AT8g7OWRz0EQ1U09JBycD52iR8KD8fSGtdJcp9tFBfoKWeb8h5uMjgcR6uWUA0MOh5d4PCcrn/khu4B50S04SduuWD/N0D0bdRfGcCzT5iHAcKP4i5CYBlRSYjPBzSiJSJpWv50kAmc0GUONB8Lq5/owoEmRHPjECOjOgOqaslCRTWQVgqaVUS9fC25ep5hfGJDpvVNj2MbpN4gwHqj0hFaEqxQqqGwbzjAesnliDoSynjRkNFypBt@TgCQNQgeP0YdQ7ij3u6@onp1fM0IiH9i4OefSEdFRuyT8B6xfO2c5KpreBQAhjYKgCGlAZ5VYVWUWULV7mSAhwCwL4i2M5AM153ohVI5TzOk4qHiABT40SVQRfLVBks0c3iGNyxFxRsSU7/UTXpK3s826mdTWaekeIb7VlD1HDLYRZ6iDlTlUkmhFlKVDHN7cHD4aPfs4EGGCHIBwfEklmaHsKlI5TLvNPXvmxN36KMRBmHdV@wW8wzJU24meV9K8n7W70erPR3NcBABfuEHp/PGqWSDBnP0EX5OiUVMxmoPaVWGhrGS/kFzPOHNTjMZLmZl4piIN0HlBj0/HucQpTGtOKLg0ie9IQwWzOdtwAaE5wbQRloBNeBTtw4IHmNUo0Exl1t3IhsIqyA0mZ4Abt/E76slUStTlNomad9RSfIM9TrDkE5J21aS0gXURDBsJD91kzUNePOApyCXqQl/7ZfAsPqYixSruDN7bxa0X2rinxPhoEJ44In58ODIL/48CXxGGJ9rpjz@@lJ1yJsGYCjtcSIj6gcmPY@XSjIVnxDsjYg8h38@q@HVwgBduzcTUT@Z1dsfGmYv9SaaxhhYTaOfSqe1RiPHX0OSzhiIkzsGYqijvMbX0K2/5BZ@klxqty3In7ht6Vfky8ePHkKTP9Xp8evWi/PthJQB1pavYRHURgqBHhw/PlEdV3d4cYzvw1AISuEXEfxERGjtkdvKntPcZzgsmoS9ECjnQPf80rt7szN18EQd6amkmmQHnzApAxrFqKsiE4JqRjrNQxHVlnG@VEcNbrlxOf560KBQQ0fv17pQ0Re1udu4TA34mgevYTSJAiTRUBQauweBGi48VmrdwO8jPzx7/KiRrKsEY22s6RXJdDdEDkAUijD0RPeu46izJdQBqkKxymNnFynCwJVOcs3lstQltZkElnVjfh7ZVNmCKIrJBQL3UpOMj3FO42aT1pwFFszGegMd2ND22cEZl4GwzkTn0dHC4W1GiRY7lt8I0mDohpSCDoGzU4RpNPL37lE3po2j0VCyWR5QszaH2FzA3FQo9ji1uaM2eqmwItWxsUYFgCIqkmq5V6jWGFjebKG0YzswRDR6wEPec4GENFB176Xhze65gG2NQJ3APXYusrGV3y4fG3vf/LJyWnyQ0rqfy1yGe@XaFohozjiaAUe9EhlbBDTW0Rh20UygAkNNlcbqhS3le1mtnC3LpZ5eKujlbK6sFfRcpQtcotbPl7u9SkktFbSuBIObR4OIIwO/wMMx9Mdk@3dLdhNjVgYZv9@XgVvvFSr9ipLN5fLdcqGXzef7ZVnN5Yo9pdytdG/n2hb5QXEroLs4dqxS4E83M3exG7TdD83/Dw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._Vd 2=>+u 8 >
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Sumerian is a trivial Python substitution. Cuneiform is replaced even inside strings, so `""=="-"` can be used to separate Sumerian from Python 3.
The only problem is Ruby 1.9.

- Ruby 1.8 doesn't care about encodings, so UTF-8 in strings is not a problem.
- Ruby 1.9 cares about encodings and default source encoding is ASCII, so it errors out with `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`.
- Ruby 2.x cares about encodings and default source encoding is UTF-8, so no problem here.

Parallels with Python:

- Python 1 doesn't care about encodings.
- Python 2 cares about encodings and default source encoding is ASCII.
- Python 3 cares about encodings and default source encoding is UTF-8.

The standard way to fix Ruby 1.9 is to use `# encoding: utf-8`. 
Polyglot already has such comment for Python 2, but Ruby has stricter rules about it – the encoding comment can be on the second line only if first line starts with `#!`.
Fortunately, there is another way to specify source encoding – to use `-KU` command line flag, see [here](http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/ruby-19s-three-default-encodings).
So **Ruby 1.9 is supposed to be run with `-KU` flag now**.

Comment: Do previous programs also work with `-KU`? Otherwise I'd think it's cheating.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yes, they work with `-KU`.

Answer (score 6):

## 243. [Re:direction](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Re:direction), 11320 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEUCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZJkEQLBNgAKJGtVtfMJDXXE7tynclc13h84zMziRM7SVV8UzfXk4pdrvJ8TbnyyT@gnS8pV8rzDyZrrQ2ApESq1ROnKiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FjqaO/zVr6J4sSPbnA1M22Oe7nqs5xjnuiOxnRm7rxluXs1GIgi17QwmI93y3EokyhTGLP2CHVhdowduzLPPdMt4ozvgpzI2duyBo42YN9Q8sBgQij3Qzbejtx7r2qORZvVcgMwydqSBZ3/SPWNax/UcresZtgVeOcaeWaY26vQ0BhC6M3Z0j6LPM4iie0Zhln0KjD22HVfH5Lu669roWGSspo/G3qwBlhJAaI5hP9p@8tm1wGXGPtMgZ2NTn17Li5Jhzw3d6V0LoSjsi5P9/euuKvuGaFts/2b@lCx75riaqV2PP8e2J5594F13z7PtgW5pTJXKknrds8B2HO1GkCJzdK3XN0xdMqwuE9lQN8e6w9CF9W0HmszTzVKmlGlvz0NKXQxbmntei7YeXExzBi542uc6GHVoibGh91jfsUdMs9wLSEkpZ@bwGG15GR26kEFANPbKhdA9nbmWMR7rHveE4uoOeUPKzDSsswjHviPH7k26hjUAOB3qdTzxqExupAvBGmzs47CEBhalWuBgkIVje6QvtoULyAu5dsd61@gbXV45@tTTLRfK60rMgLa7MEyT9XQTAsxj76aZa7OJu@DUMbWh1JUiWLmYChudmcxg3fGYcS8oBmRpP1Ni@sh@ZbA34G8OXTYdj5hrjMDb69r9vq6zN/p4CMEjPTvC4OqOrxUrtMV0gLF0KNru0beg0jysS6sP@eqxzgIcZIIyTMXVLBvqzmGWNuKo0B3PqOgQTRiib9sSuvds3bXiHruwnTPW0bsalhkTc/VBX5uYkKLRx7YAJDBcNrLhDS1oMcgWBPawIjBuTCyysiCYTNC2@hh6JbatjbgCDR008YWjAXI4rt@InjEC1DC8uMt0zTWQXEEQV7d6hBbjkJDZUNrFFmfnBvQ6qIqJQ3G7ukN4T/EyLAVEqYWImrhwDA/QAUuxzY50zWEnjq4nOZLqblcbI4ouJgmJ2ZiChwWRCCtrtfje4X4csJOHkLQxYKOTPfnm5xGNSXUWa1fhrgtCNbL35AG7jLXQzAkmYPDYSWhJVn/HXLnV0uGeKh154FxFINYI1IrJZHvsyZo4hgyKHmRQ1tCIJvFclcbmQsKsdq0NFvoMh@pBawAFYF@kqWTdieMgaZ9XqnYGhTZtawD1CYV1JhZv8kIGmgDwr@emmX6uIw7wNrIvqIZPhoAh8AfQBbLCRxuqUBhvoB/6NRqk69rmhOAgpOthZ4RagaAY40GffcH6mmFiEPDHqHiuHd0F5MQwE6uHLT8yLL0nsSAbRHIc6IjnkJwGkZID9IbRAmGhTAEwNIRNRUWv97/9e73BAOLZ7nZtp@ej6xeA7F0aFzXKLIxsDBHWtjSTsgVwaUydB4cEzjXT6BGJ06yZnwRlglK9sCdmj1FHvTCgyw01oLQ6UIeup3Mktyce5DHNRtoZJ4cGx1wo@EjrQMNSApQ2FVtk93ehlbrQzQlnxNHE65eYON5jcVd@kdiqJLY2WjpkLiklN2OyPKgCwkmb5AS2@G2Y88X20jjhepprG73IeOYNbUtlYpcJ3bo91q1EfCmOeDrudOJJCcl0Ilk16l2pb1i9RLwGuNiAhOPJarfebRqV0@q14ItJQjQXGA12Vz3RTQpIaqhTnMsj4CwkoGRfiL5pwc9221jl6C0tOGPFXHc75w5R4lsQL21EEKBDkmvq@jiRkZQkkgmEW1lu9FhV0mtx@AWuGKepeDSeWiw6xQAlXSoodtYTw0ayZY6HyGxApVjuGGiug7jb1QB7XBzRPODn0qxDeE3DIFAWookXehyodgcIaYBH1CV5l8PwIhJKP4Z5F1ruyXpvoSMDEYC@7Lk3qLFpI2tAecKRB0iHhYlqA2gaCMwLss0LwlMil@UinVlAUDC2js5KYseAToDdDWi6j/MLZQPwrMphIDbeSRZoz0ib4ajG@YJ5h8ExTWMjIA/OjHV1pDlAfHQ@oGAiE@p/LjC9zO6zjKjm88t97EYX8xx5W/wKiPQb@daehIVf7ExIaFgfeGxTswYTbQD0wrYgiNbt6mPPJ1RQEtcDUnR9vCFH0R88JXcYid2/njYNIgFvNE8DiTxvPX8o1JC6@Dy7CAwZ8n1cEGA9wwGyBCP5tdQB4Pxa4sJLBFnKwEthTRYCDgCQTJ/q3YkHVA0Q@GJodIeAs5g7i9NFPghdTx6cFlMHyi72w6QxM0rjnhqR5NAJs7E2ChFb9GY8MLhiVI0lB2r8RYfbY9bc0YqI7TCLMBAsuEqyJgHufSDOkW3ZKyKFigyjRZBlH94OwIkdI0cMA1fAdlFnDdnksImgzYBqQM8H/Bt63titwDhheMNJRwJMkU@c2YF3aCGyyJ4zMzybmzum3QGy7EL/lIMU5O6kY0yvFYjcwjZ85UbOgQHru6wOI/frCWBdIt53gWCS@y4CL3gJRLgpCv4UAJCAJKioRN8lUrwPROV4ZnUTwhJSCmkmYN8VkmDAgGHVfI7M23I2X4HT9Vwi2GJmJBmhZNfpkkFc4EkxegSnbEU@WSraHfMY@UQQ4NHXTFeHtzUxTbROLE7lEpxXSLLLyCefAGlLUHLGaGwaXcNrc192757PU7ANEPCQbeojz5SEMJ/4krQEBAVg/OGHQ0uefUzMbiIJBfnkailh3XFsh6frDR37gpEDgkUWK3XXHiF1Z8@J4UIOGmRaw0LZ3h9LaSjVVrIQ4ZhK/HI8Lr2yDStxGd/Y2IhX4g0YMTc2tsBUQ9MWmlJg2iKTSCaEk9BEIdJkQt8mhUC30/hVM4h5mjzF7jDF0f6NMU5ozUole5rWmor/VvGdhHqGEQOgRXxBPPFkvY7GZFJoXEBBpU5/ufS7OOoddx1j7FfC59q5xu1@LWSpGqDhbAcFgyoyL7fXyajuAHcBwkB3mHDirWamddq6bPVSrat4GkMnq1q9A4WC9BIjaeDYE2BDks1cRVROk8lmFpiPTj2eiW8mEiURxDiQRJKflpIpjdd2Iq7DaJhoteJQqX79NLtDh@KbptVkMqwqyAcyPMBrJ@LSZQnS7yRPk6k4hE3G0yC61eNxqJkuVoJLhca@tFRBh0@/wStmN5WKUPcGqRTvG8MpuKHQuxz8aPLmDdIuHkcnxDBzonEub@wDyAdWACuh5zWhNfDq9BnS0aU0PrP7XCraxcfeo/2IPqXW@uxwf@9pnZIZau4Z8BTiAGFl4JWhVpyeBNTAnPT0yCoYIBtg6s5zghMHmPig22WizQhM7PJMLAwXXbYmNqA1xHjaTDRHy0Vwh5Df3aUyUCTkTiFv41@6QZY4@Mo8hUnuA8XePX60ND82OgN@gnVdE5lv0eEFAKu8yR179ApljAo7IBnNAgYTcAv4y144F2DZloi0MBDn7MWE@IQIQJAbclvISRhLMBhx35iCSBzF@RSf9UeOFbn/XdsC4VSXnhM1FBgQcpyq0qWV/P8RZ6SkrjvvncDpg3Fsal2g98vRtQTWggiBAsnyap9k9UbE14UDkuM/VEZgpbqahfXXM0hOnRjuEKsXZAkcBZw@1CoKqTi5Q7V2wLrA5Q6gpvWp4XGpFXr4MQZ5qLmJJMpJ21zOQCxDHhkzFUzbEQNrd0HC14FXRl8@XcL2rHPDsS2sZGkPogZSVMU2uBb5quoFNNrePlAfrK/fVZFDjd1wVhbqdjHW65XbdaF3WbZpD2y2CQCImpLEEfvAwulNkHI8bQw9ynhDFbQ9sEHUX8ZBXQ8nTAvZUN7UEFImeOkVjAJsdaHnAGvKfHzw1R6wIUo@k4H8B7YMXWEhF2K5XkZ07LI5gL8EYCLeYEt@pY@HM2cJnVzbnzfxaPKQOiafydKAhYRc@T38DQVd7OTcBfp54NULTKvKvkcyAU7eLcrVS6Vf4lZ4t4ESRq85o2tQFUuR3mjwefsi4WrJS3QrnCoQ@yPb0@QvJCDR@IgghywaTHDl@EZcFkV8CuTF1AaTe/q5jFRqHvN0T@@ujHuq610ZfXFwY4FhZfUEnmuqpgWXRQ8oJn8HdRCGvF7@QSqFhJ1yF6bNMw2D/Mlwokf07tBmQgtEjMWSCTBADEFWFqHmgQFEuSQM5i8HRTx7AmJdTzeNkeEd0IS9aaHsIhHxlpBq@b67QG/mERwZOjDkfMJhPsjgpPp8jLIGHP4pUHKKFUR8iVepo/fkzXlsj23bAbnSZQrNKahh1Y98D9l2xz3Jm0IEPNQeje9uMM4/OXyw1z7aPnlYlyeuI5tGB2hET2@PQJg1oTusuTBvOEO4B7hjWPbIgBIFUb45M5/atseZB1w1uNsVxYBBHI8etB8d7DzdfvotP3M0ohujialhHiuxawBhHMcEc2s0XbtjA29hTdbGBMzF4c7hoyCWz589OthuP9g7OjxZiObVxDQ0ZSqPzwbrCvQ5gjBFyvCqPzR7y8s5JKYuzSL4xAZlrioD2ZSJIjxFdOOJolQmoQeyyDg8iiLOAms4z@0wVcmUy72OVirphV43lyv2tX6vl1OVUr5fyqv5DDyKhbLO3hK4KOpTmrkBE58VwQkkTAMyTy9FygUcDoiiXeBYZivzFfrekrluPq8Xc2Wt3C2Xy5pa7GU1tVTU9UKxn8tk9IKS6XdKSil7a@YWsoGs1dw2ohkg6HU4WUCeQPwS8FrqDjzzwOtdsJ6qqoVuvl/Oqr18JtfrlDP5Uq@jFLVOWc/0c1lFVXpdVakEYXFGFajEEBoMuUoLWNPAS1TAMxkJBtPFJqYlxmAN2ic4sSySmHGwhoyCg@@RQ4@Jv4KMU7O@ex7dg/VjnKLx3QvoPsLV4zknS9bQ0QcsESAuIktOJ3Aso2O4fLy0sAqk0qefq/zXB/JjvlQyVxj5BS5AL5TvUlHI/dzr95ecVXI@E3EoM@fOWXLmy8/LC79@YW94rQQO48tRfHzZemV8N7xWAofx5Xl8uNy9OrprPqtAw8gKFBkuj6@M65rHCsAwpiLFtLikPvcrkd@69XQ/rZXeawOFcZcpbr5U3n7FVyva/ko5YjPvICfAiT2ygX9@ZOC8fX@px0RCCbwVEYJphOWJpLmPOl8mYeL56vUdYTEiTgwM68wmwTk0tTOSksdYwihGZ@bNkH0QNeixBHojUzd9@Pg16vTpsQIAB93rM3PkQdOe/tAPQ60mP6UXToCuysHyVO5S8h29PwEpSO4YFpo/ACaWSwTZ73SMdaBQE7jzIHivAKuwpxOQRFUpJymB2ItLJ0Cz@TzsycEhAXY0EuKW5//ZUuV7E8eDUP77P3@7B41ws4mG2oxkwdDQtvQLwo/@2hbzg6KFHqtbdz7qU8WQ6UNRdjVcctXM0LA6amp9URxqzghFLr@5AUHxAZhwC67xnPO5mOC9OpEKo0peXmdgljFi3RXQBHttSYQnRkK2aWs9qgYuChs6BXKwsXkz6FMuFC4wPDDyrEtoxcoFm28V8IYTb8KfuDvgQ81ojPG@rYv6kJm81lF0YJG1jqHf0uiOdjbp2SJwelRkzFhhBey89DRZJ/ZN7Ywb22hcXXxeQMcYDICf8N/rwC6GINuQUCpf0OtDeOFaE3csdqCxPOg4ZKOuMLolBcfkz3Ughr95LjSsrzXDpMcdGj1ELkIXYOmoonE/k7hQaca1aja1zgxF9eHHYxkmSAwO0Jx6N5XKZHHYC9d@F7cirQ@PYyWFL5dXh@Y7qXiVrBKvZL6DSuQTyFRmf0/VBxoWBi5jpJmi2lswrqXowdTx3LQClOZtxK6puYBant8c@jk0Hz1uQ3ccmbogdjlz0y3IPs9OsAVg3WqyT7b8Xt21TcPFrm2uo6DXF@DmaeJeNnosTEkbqyq2RzyTOxRD02q6YHc9XMpdg2h3oHJ8FRXXqRcwR7LXVVrXvsB7LWsxtM91/lw90L1Zmas7UCzRJJQwuitHlF73Q5iK24Hosboez1bmy@uaK92X@0AwxbEooN0Rr13DtF12TM/bqmXgQDD@XI3RizVoaJZI60GL5tXB/EyNmeTPsq5pV80c2GahNJA1eKxt/InTxzHBf9@V@oXUS1E@TL0C/si2FP@9luyfyc7Zh9qOliYcXLRfMN4yAq8iYf6i5PoCgiSBO3FWF24/U6KQkszl5XUN4HSHF9oseP8aI8u62g1GlvGM@G1g/zBAuQQGz@E8@K@TWu721Hp3I083oi1@qBALjXtm6jCQ0fNGkzI1o3xkCCWTuTux6psTfaKvpFWHnVc6bm6/RQq5e6YyfjFi/mwnzgjhXGcI9caXH@@UaxzD0XYrgdFMAzr5BzmdlfRuDDz6GEXuIzAcoeFmwIE1GS817pIUZz29veaG46Bn272lTKLPx1Kk0of5qSVG3tXpvlW44sIgrm3Vs5lMxudvFuavlyy3CV3ZMOwrgz@XEiaXecpzWJwNcRaMq9OYT6VC0xtnroiTmnejTuq6GQECLpdly7B0b4bPdU2yitp2bNv8mCYEotszkH8DrhQXfj7UlDd4I383GJvPfbg4c9Lpr5v14AOSL51C7aHgfRs2LE693qmZRVyyhl46uGa9fR5oYSL3Q6nAME@TS3zrhLme8fRnVBSpJBVv7ZGcnbU7uqnx17SQuy2@spS9Nb6QZfH5ZFrbwvUwvgI2X1GNXqNb4xlUltEDIWeoj3Sy3iIdaL1XEzd4rQWa2niv8JZovXFduLEBhMLC59Jq2wIr5dkWiGWe5gx0lGtMXBX3XdcR52BWfWXlHoy0gc4PVd1GPedTHbh1mEuDc@PqSY8K33XWhWB868ftqACd6UyfucF7ZYSPZ11oz8now1N11/p9lzYqfaijS/LKxYQP8IrW0B5aQ33IdwKFtnXdAzDS48fhbisE5N/fZcSIRi3uVFqsXdM2zbvULtJITjFtu78yX3t4UKsHQT8q3pnWAQ//9cFpQBjvqZJo4F/Xd4b6BIYt1/bssS6SbR2oiRNG/LmOkgYLPL/uTNStswRQI8H7143/g/LpQLO98Zhe7bE5celBQUU6X7eqKfcpmbtgheHxrUccd/WB3ekOjQ9lqaNrnmWcycGsELfeKt2OF2rBYOIDdJZMAyrPmUmIDfVF/2N8HaxrUn@CiQ9doWF1G1fY7sRxZlgTnm0z17Qv5jRieQ9FOJXLVyDQsC4H/urgCm/iCHB3XbCL7JZlEH8xcS2CESOOTLeoZ4BpUdbOKi1t8VzoHdksf6zjja6VnzK1sIb7MdOi/tYHmiA0FmZvwX0Jf5YWpFcOWNZwMnBvkjs@ad8DNgsfK1t6e4CHmq81NG9UGIU0y3@tq2/VlHELN7zb0HIT/dYVlvytSywEp5iiZhvwasML2nCydurMNMYufzKxr65kGm4uI9@Emq0Wnf326el9vh6Cpg9xeyPbwYNEwFaIXUd3uzidjhSZ81Cc@lj2ACizaLI5cAC7sgg3V65XN//iqCd@@UQfaLjN8pGBOy7NFZgBMV9fxL5LxN@caK7xzYnt6SvjvL6YfZcoH2sDo/twqRWCCIPa9ffk8ddSF0Cnmw1xMTRcOs8RGG6Zg0KE4yiMONcG/n@V9HZt@j48JX37NMsC4@TvBWfiAQv2jIcGXEBAf21lWqtm5u0xyZEzMt02KW94NFPrv1di2OpNAbclfzEZjSeu/1qdOu3bWZyyHp2Ru3thAIkUXwNlZkPN9FZPay/M1AL/5Q@Yc@M6rvwrw7QH7KtShgG7BgM4MulrkG4Hhu8jzYPeYa1AZEr/jounOBEiOrxwrwEv9CwTDcvwbp/08TwN5KbgjQXigw@eTJQf4VO6/7ExiCera@XRrRwNjPWzrokH5T9WOuBkGDDxmA6yozE8S7@I@34y@q4fYTDaWPrFogx360JQBYdY25p4Iu78v22MKdw6xlTYtFRYQA@W@Obe42fJAEsGwy7fEvshvlQH4XDimrO5ae1mhBXIZ1jAwK2nzTdDBFLGA53UHTylTZx3CLc9xtNVNBQ8sFdJQ0czGJk@SqSCwWUyeqB3cXXyTnl4Yj8G9g6GuzEQ49FTHbcWXKMx6wNj0Ed2VzOhznp3Su6Yol8xlsyFcW2sd6DtzblpNd@2LvIHmqet4bVospEkxtD0QVwyzI7uvKJZxAXzOkH4ZqYe6lMSXdYjFO@potftciYdp/OW@tGCNF9hx2Obn7q@BSdCMgSDBz3uvj4v4W7npbFxpTh3s5yH53yDit7jR/3WFdTRO7bJnzjSrCEWlsG3I2iOobvyI8OaTMmNicDprRaK@MbfjFTEiRF3CF3wwgCJPNwPjNvb@OZi95rcBQz0uebSJoHVEtDS3uO770Maak7XxtU23/CRa20Lh8g@QOXDzdV8M0MHEGgK5E7rTgJNBB/IqjnqjOixXoJZbu2negcP6nXo1KmnTVexm8sHznzHa0e@AkKH3b/AEkcgJyU/PNRdF/KWa90Y04NI/sVKVAmSe2Lo3Tda8q69iWagZY1k4JUdannrHDBDpi56Q9yZKXveOpLxxDib9O6wQhYsu0xGOq50L6/3rEUs2x0SVtir1/ZDsuvo/oZv3FsIJCAwI@0Vt28G9Q9LkF6XUAOAm/aP8YCb4fhHhV0pUFIUpSNPhI/B5nsWRS0FExS0PduRGMElEloqlUxGeCDcCDGwACyAIi0rqIGBK3BxGXAmHsEafdZsstjltJKpKFeszoSKwE5Peax4kT6AvemYVKQ85cGbMe20HouLYjwWb1kVlomH4LoJXPlKcG0Jtm/Qi@d3XgVcfZJNuo/CEle5hgnoB6i9ZahZPVNnzyxanQI2yuF6ErgSjhPcdfmLP@z5Sm1IedPIAKkZKgSVUtkjfWhfbPF0/dSBqdBQKQ7GAQKWyVU0iLvbDLh7rzvkumzsC/Zs/6Tka8jwNWCB5YjPl4S54I2LCzd42s/jjcdzE57c8hMOQwWFApZxMrKACve8oSuxY4MO8k2c@dZ8Xy@Y5Tk4M9tLswPW03GDG53PpMUI07bP6MwG5uQXf8j1gtApTf/0XJA86QNaSBEPYyqkjKPbtSeQ6yCSN7pj@yAJrGQQqSa49EfqqMg9iWcXSWEJYKQYqOugZLjOjt3tYybusTgqusLj9VWjn4htP/3si2bmtP6OjWT9P39bTl76FSd8KpYLrpBmAUj1ChFr0TsP3nPfOBNiU4EnGB5hNXxG8IK3Byrp4kiGp1gDHLPtsd9rSOUSaRgKsdE/uZ9AM7VzoLdjRNqaCGH1C9LbQWelLOz/pC3MhQ4G1iRFzXtdPZaY8NUo8dhjeUgQdZ9oYOL6nehQJ@qgwCCxKXvLhohkwEwo@QzYeEWaqPZkVN8Jtj9nF7elyw/0zoS2Zp6rkpqvU3Fi7XqtQSYgUjaqH2q@aE3VjNiaFvdOZTeo1FZr@mlG/RJq3XYg1D0Ze97ekweXMamRefvW1WZMEK7iVb6NHshE7PLo4Gjv@GT75NkxtMJVQH72@WGagNYgFtH5uKFtkmInqBfkUT6C/oQ2VLOQYDGN1VBvYDIZWTzJRKB@XQuiEOPGBdK0FPoDwVeFd/UF/5sAPk3rGyzAqAMYm7ANAdmw1rDwkzGqp2J@WF/FDmGZgTQeO1BYMXhYYQUtpaoSWB0qS4TKumNVsfWF3eJud6mxD8Zye7VtrQTBGgvTa4b@vIgrq@Dq76TcYxgo/@fLzWO5vdwEc0u5ATR0DcLsbx88evZ0bzkY4Bi9ierWy3n/CB8nztjTOI8T6BSik/N@QFzJqwtMoADc6g9mXLOh7l3oUCyfOHZHPDBhKOVfiMwRE2qmjpo1T6u8LhIJygHyIFUs1rUThn1jupDFYIxeiO6SFzEkAvtCGHWQcUnwY46ShkgJr6AYGKtfXUHXOyIi7tPruLvI/qSDHodFwzF64vI@t2aoCkcdl8F/YVQKTOopmzJ/OFNOmchUuE3dGkCBA9hklY9RLMYrQojxvAthflG5H@Sp90qjyXPaOe@fzINR2tTGqEnMh35ie3qFvZ7YdPo/ICYhf0F6JTWuiJOalmuYJK0CIHsAyxyMWxTfwf5xHbkzzpoRfV/EuYmFAxUAcbWY/vlcz0HdsfzgJNdPx6vc9lWhBUMliZSur/oo5BJcdm64BghD1Ah95HFMoJRYGr/gqFeV9D6wbdMFnqQHwzdwKB4OtcCcSHSci5/pEi0mRAEnpZBlTDMhgrBu/aZqLBhKL0Dc677kgWMERzG7C3HGaxuiCDU3ABnYPxpWQa2qJElVmOdMcLdWI34jSJCFCpnEoTcyFwBXKAls6fL73/49rhiw5YH5@755mtkB22/6tj6YfyvwURSw/ZPQpoLtB9z2QsYmu6kNzU/en6hZe/YN8PK@cKNMSBMCTbJUlrC1saW/ODhibhd1lGJbjkC0nTcTUhjEOcOC@jJGgBTn1MYIzlOYN@E8nkTzC0ARwCvAD2RvkKOh9HTnNIE6sSqyjBnHKXSJdszpU76CTSqyXk9QNSQwYXIhX8gpMmRSPA8iJK0dAzzAwyNMJitAEyPnxrj@stNltVqNCW5XM/V6ocpxQ45pL7LCyzCjMYCNcEGhySAMBJmHAL@GHywR01JKEoPiQBZX4kjTejZHNeAGE2QAkCQ6W8E5f2A3bb@qAI8tfeoRxzQLBCAg2Ja9oBM2iEiEiHjcqMDwenecH8rBWZ2FDiotNoPwHMGOEawirELW5gvW8lrWqa/IkgHi/WQF6lpg/kcrtFtyzEI9JjfVKiauK0XE0rD7x5aNk2P7kFuWUGU1KyuF5AKGCn5UkF/s6m8hSujcQCy6uvHKHrvbu3sHnx8eHd9Qr0OQ8etgcRZv1FItUUo3T0NDPMz3cqXu7MvHj3f2g6pczNV8egoh5jsUr2dzVWrXc7om9ef8/NPNtMnjRkJK5q4R09YfcZ92@t6Mfe4rLwDu8uMXN1JNJC@vmqe1RsuK3kj@7SqVqVFpE5ELTC2XFKbGr2cTsxjqRj9B3eiuFBzuVfBkLx758uyz@Tlh32HBg4MHsQAFiEhyALUCY4MMHPL5mblCC5UrZ3eJ9PE5HFJkGeZoAfIkUOOOXWuuf81XPDbU3KFpdCIwdvdQGR9XGxLoxQgVjkju2DS8RDJCsx915ICAiCV8Ze7TylSiNbcEqU2luNLsNl1mQXzJCHQCiC9@NHGH7Mges/nU0wM9MD0FRoQ9mPBFGJ19PhkBXJ9eT3UksTqwJiIEhoqKh1nlAjX0LF@V2TSF6uIgvSYqNPMLLo16@cQ0KQ31ac8YAAFPJNPQ0z9VgKMKD1tjoUm9mRUHGsdr@DM89rJYpR@l0W46j1xrapJh9fRpAlW0VE6BNUX3@MXz83hSuIEDpFZvN1DEdU2/XtARNc/vEXPddNc6WznU4H5NAWK5jGpu8Nw4NAukeOw5j8AI41OiP9LGLDEhxY8ukxhZE62ElXY9J8nEBtcdYbFUigRqeJEHMMwI2icTIQ5LoJ7khFyH1kFX1@rh640xZk1Fkk7BTIkkWQwn03ZhKMdpqGQEBCQIUqFo69i2rII54tgrccyDMOgfIU1UDLUfrvAmfYW4Tgn9FOqCSs0a9xY0@Mx7IK/Vcrnit8YyqSkzQIubVF6SIdoVJCRgUKF@/WPAUGuozxsVv@N8LpCF@9/QLUuHCgKcGWkwBmsTQDInmQ6@3pCe63@mFKI8iw/9c8WQ0WW90HvxSxOX/2JyleZlqlcwpr5s4aDa94fVmfz3ZUmuXiZiZn0mA6OTbCRiw7qSym6mUjFrMxGzcKi/dw@nc65iwEm0JZCOpgAkxsxkFfAZOI96zKrGtFoi1qurmxQCrCCfXUKAd64sXca0Kzl2D0bqNLg4vPMmYi6pFsxIknIF@cMeEpPTgDOXqImNPt2AyceMVArzIMXamIF3cus4RTS7dSzTzFHVZ0TlwcjvbteoatgSNz5cwSvQd/YbGgi7ioTd387dDoDnWqGzq/zW8B484W/giRlGG/R0d5HzF5Z97k5YfHoXJ61PXJEj1@0IFThNQCWiNa0lk0BMfvWrqFJgQiK2Vciep@L5TBUeSrXI8uzTWEvNRVn0Pkjq8qbgCJetB6VzpvfVwmtRbGp96fXp0dnR0ZfJViIe3T18ISg5AC2yMt13vYpMXXOxj7ui0U05EpU3lXtFWX758iWwu3A1G1JjEUo6TTbF@GkzUQRLo1jcTBdKm@n78TZlJZlQ1eQxMwyZtYyx2@vBbQ/pAyqJKL/Y1hamBQb4M99tNO1zt3lmOIjvGoQNvD4EV9HyUdYqatpmKqfet6qSmlF/8fONq/TlUbv2i@@MZH0DX4f4@v7VYzQfK/lPNzY@3dnJ5dJQedx89NXRt7a3t3MP0vmjZn4rJ2Y2an/xZxsbqlpT5Y1T11VO482zLwU1kxOkX/wsfnT0zbbrYvvhlWUKGPFZglth@Tw7Y2/gOusz/JP5TW/BrKG503@DAyQwy3UiNvF4Phs/fhHH4r6JKooSndGvTdWwwZTGVvG//PDwddSLNlT5uQNvL/o6WihFuREMYMsGtvNoI1pDsMJVdCbX63UwFv/Lv4Pwjc8hHvSZ1eDRyAdxFWbRhlinIG@jjQIYFFWFdP/bt78diTamiAiNg32mNtRNjitK6Z5yj7EpXoy1okopd3gfnIOL@yxcTFYUtRW050JzY9OGzkMoPLQrsxfcwnYPMCPKfGwgw8fA4bd2Chv3Xz5gtQYMtXhVKvdDVJNZsSTYNnTnKtgehe5PJREuqR3Yq2gV/SJES/V0mycf4mp0wXCtwOGT@WUP7R8Jt4fXX/5/f/mjv/wh/X5E93@KRINlcbF5njqFduMXExpIn3w7e2yxx/yyLPjDHVjRBR3AZLF5WaLRRgMf9PdtZKL3NTffpxFaCGIe5MNwlG4k@g7aBLGPnTeWLtaQ5yWjIvBck@HxQsnmZUMU2IJrA370hyu04nODXHxnArl5bbDGbdet1DcSbUabp6cV6kx3v9jquKPnkagIpCGVego8o4/Md7mewS1Jbd8WInU0Ev07vRoRFr2E6zQlXl01pRepatX/AytVDW14cRPk6fRKFGsvGqlUk/LWbPiZrImnDYm1eX7p8aIG8aZqzVrd3qVbamMdifGcHS/Y909fNJq15Tj8aO7fT2Fnvg/xNGKnDJh4qNmr2lXjqlm7uqrV4F@j55X/Bter2o0/veZXdQ1QeF2dYqO3mnKjJbf8Bj0FuyQ30EWSW2BowLsNgM1mJHqJ@MKap6SNqi42lUL@VGTUJzYr6Nd1Gasom2pWzk8/LeypkagqCPImer3FkQn4i3Ikilx6mTPrZXJ4@f7rf4136/3X/waskDX85Bf5PrTw13mNv0dv8Pfaw99JF39PX@Pv5A3@nnr4O3Lx97iDv0i0zhiwSLGtjJk5zyhnyhkYDJYBDnWYGSo9HBIyOsvMMjOWGdlKD0w6/DJgMjJ9lhmwjJWxFAU8weCxjIemPrwG8OtDLA78jEwGI8@cM0jFxIGGVLnS@22bJVuRJhNe6sDbSEpcysSlQjxunOYL49dCOt5uNeOn1ajstloy5/qYmquSDt@rK9Zu7z150G7L2A9aj@3D@f/wcLRovfU/OrQfH9ojG/6Hh4ePodVT91PifbjqjVTNf21FG9WtVkVEZJZ8tI7Kta1WIyuiuZACFFXRLfWR1zxGeDc2WhEQiZ8/v6g@f47/i/PqRZUMoRUM7WoI4INxAzhyB4jgebVKBjTDdU6xkg2NF89boYkb5OcX4PScAZMe/uUl29/B3/jf6//4GUs0T5PQDy6vagm6kvhLJi@vLq/8ZyOZSPiWRA1@6AB2DHJ51UAjAV2CqZlIniavrrgbPBPJGo@wgWnUGhR4DggUI8pTTbTiwL@AXJnw18NarWkmk6x2wCWcGdfe0tJKskqbTmIdXA4DWUpJEkQ@V60qm9ys5tRqNedbiqVqteSblUKhWs34FpCLqoERYHRX61axZ1Wj4yRmh/e3RAZn30hnflyoCPfuJfyvLGyNxyAnK@XM27ehU7vdM5x2G92zb98KbQF3oNTLebBnSm/fQp@PJ0GCfmL7a59lkIcVWZ2nMNRczfOcxBtjnBZwi6orJEmrbSZjO634L3/wne@04nXcgUCuOQUjwDhZvlYr5BqNQg7MhVIyWRVifEtLYpAqK8mrmCzw0oG8G4/6XkqpmCTXqzj6s2iNbTWgR7h4scurKLUHy@WTic5MT16CS@CmlMvckeUKiVKq7P/qG0nW2GT@r9lsZlO5zeLm/dPT02vsNVKt6qVWV67ql1oFJ2Ouql1fbToeTdDu3cuWoc5KmWor0m4/2D7ZbuMX13CVGQYaho5E/yK4gjh24k2aOcuXT5tYotNWPF6p3ufNXsqzaLzqw4lxIKWsVKaCR0E8N/p4XmlKsV67N6NjphSzMIJFxrTbp5hhPVwwdZjd72@AI7QY6@DatqubZqBn/sJ2zN6F0dM3ItGjR9u7eydptQaDobq/vZtWj5/tRBW05ud28s6i/ene9oPDZxDg6NHe9vHeZwdf7D07Anc38uqNpuuaPtH1i/ZkcvEaVZHrbX0MrvOrrXcNV3v1ShvTxaqc8l1cvP/J997/5B@@/@kP3v/0e@9/@qNffv2j78H9h3D/gL9/8G/LeXz@8ut/8gfvf/@n4Pif4P6PcP/8l1//7rf5TfY/hfvPF9z@1L8X4PjNKtHGJl6ACCW1lNqEoWWzXAZkINdaBNL6zV9@/cOf/fLr3/ox3P/Mv3988/7tn6@@f/Td9TeG@@Ef3A7zg38H9x/xuALYH/w@d8P3Dfjf53C/9eP3v/Pv@f8v/B8af/r@d/4UH77lH//4L/78/Xf@g6qW/uJfvv/eD95/94fvv/ud99/9/vvv/gP1/e/@SyWz@PiD9z/64//6J3/0X//k/6L/H9Lzj@7yf//jf/xX/@9f/f9/9Sf@/XO4/z2Yfv5X/wHQ@G/@@Cf4/@Ef/81//An@/9U//5s//r//5jf/BRl@jxv@@z/7t/z519/53l9/95/@9Xe@XvP83q3Pr@/g/vX/Ape75/Mu8dylXB/r8vWvlZ//mdqYpwI4QDrhmQrc485MZ1UWybCM/4BO@KN/9P53fwNw@3cAEmz/J9jgzy3g9X2yfPnlkl@KphTE1Jdfgiz2pS@TfbkI9H3G3srA6WbuvwWAL8mXXyyEgkT/H4QCMOZDBWBLiRMI7lTkzr/8@p/@DN3DkOj6G4vxZQLXBdgYAr8Nivh97MxhMRZhv4/k4P1Pvv3@Z//g/U9@7/1PfhPHAjFXTm@nReUDE5YAmL8DHAIW7gIHgArKYyA4b0RUMGzUcIItoqRevoRG2AATCDKbkXwWbBGlQWYFzRAQxOxNimSawjkJuKeRXBlsOA@WgkE4xb1S4LWTwo//piLTOvgRKH41mKGxUcLJMZTY6xAvBuJh0u0SCAdsukOxQMh66ilrb9anPGAKHRoUA8MModNTQVGFVKn@ABKsTx8wjAsjT0VewvtlvVGqTxsY3TvKAsSR2oEkAQo/SpyaNt6BvU5xAnxk@uAdZKVUT6UaJXCpU1EptXSb0lTyVDgqe4pRudGdMdwtuHWfsU8FpSTwKQWoSuZD4zM1h96iGbct8G@lNv3i0D8w0r2J4aGdplQ/3I37b6EzhfcBIF5RxE1mcIsi5uY@eE95VClKFl4pHgPUXMqftgwdiEFJRVLUvimyQPqQh4@5anxwxuiwOLFYDEy1hpAV2ocgkzHnrOJ6moPrYMQvVphQKAvojJt2@E7E2BGJbpsPNuGpwH9vg3bfUkmqm5FYHOcD4ixISUxl7Zwd5YUISki2TSpAigDZp@CD9/37YIYaovfcLRKdh@MyAy15AoOfY8lIgj5yk6RJBx2ZIBZ57A527Clw82lBSCsFXMpI8imJyLfsSqX@TskVI/Am@wQ/r@N/6AUaCz8yLNVqWOmNS5FmR9AIjGEh0mj4a7ZMiTSO904A/OSQKWpGYsD7X@aKai6fy6vZQiFfVJVcoZwr5EtZIGWFTF5VlXIuVy6Vi1dUlvtADdKVzU6@1vh7N67/4@@tula74hVpfMmmEk39XkUaZp1vGYzh2q3QyghVmqWhmos1M2n8qdksPCGPaSVfPN3YMC9FLHKL9qld4uo4ZDNyKU5xqvkTuFjkkwj7BNzggkRw@Yr5Gw4ODqv@4jJ@Io8vMAtKHpAnGWkB8vDooBUvLy8X7kh046uvPNZoAGMvHuxHooD0w/Cj9KLRk4YSfdiuN3F08h0w9uDgi4Pjg8Mn0oODY2C2v8XUbEaKRK@urvrhGgBZdXZ4eBhBagOiU1bB8FddNplMyLcD9qupFlFVUc2KWUVUsvj/gEHF/93hVfir@IRQWTXCIuPFqwp3BBH5HhDpewo35gtzYwaNNf8YcyNCi41NQKLTCH4HqXkaqcmh5wmeKn8CjQHoa7FHuN3Ws9mJzbd17ujdNRC7Q/5F713HBtno14fZ0awz7vXA4MdYQ6@HGuq7dEeGN1wD8Ww8wrNXuvO/LIa9UQcyiMsOHGAHHo5p26sAiuzZ0ZpSPg41U@C6PqmmAPCnB589PFl4n@xt7z6MFNjO4ZMH1155HyjPHu3tn4TWIvcNgubDKL619@jRdav/AppYJWF4g@WL6TQMLfDAd5ouekuxFwGIIt3yIZqY3ChVHf3ePaWuvBNrXow9q@@8Sz2ZjErZslLOAwJAqQc6yO220YOyRzVPO3JiLjt6hFI8yuL1hmZeXrFcEST69hfQ54BZaE7YaTUfbeyxRuQxbjMsK/y4jOFGHoJ8PcJvCuH3w7wInnzt4XeDcbakgx/wnYzZWkd4oRMaHWMwhMHgwg4AIh1NY3B/7AXhF0VrqLZbHTyeBrnd8DFXgOPattFnmYhEM7tquZQvlbNqKV0ql3J5pZDPpxU1rRRLxTIQ5oxSUgqlfFlJl3LlbA5GDvDNl4uRKBBUoy/LMCoqggDvCkRrdVENfg2/J2BLw0Ykyueo2Bv8Mn1UC@0TJugQRsAPMrkebaLeNOqCmsMTDlmFQYwa67Lo/v5uZn9fEHbQgjPYuxlB6KElX8pkijuCoJPPLoxuqiDYPAx4AZjHLZnMzq4gTHgEqERDEIZo2Ssguy4IBlp2t/f3MZ1XaFExPICdcR9uMQNLEcAstGSzxO8LwuswOoDb5gnlKKd7aME00Wef@@yCnyB8FuQnk4EYnnI4HsPDoKzb24JwwC3b2@jzORU8z7P6DbRs0yUIDlgACQVhAIaBo@uWIHTAiKgoCF0wdWcauOEnB1CpguVpgjDjFYRVJAhTgta6ZwLwpb47JvPw4UNt6PX0Ab9mDn93IWvgY0wne/udzz7rDAYdZ7a999lT9Pn884faq9nE6Qw6frBOGy4bwoDP2Wh2/YI8HrTbmrnS5xvgY13zac/aOuatrb2GPPnXABMZtT8Hn8/BZ7ri4rHBNQLQDl47I3jvaB3yCS7yofe00xGqiKjebKzjhB32GfqweHqkdR27ivZpfSOeiKdnzULmtErObJRIXmaqV@jbT9BH7ZAyJi9nzWk9cwqySlH1T2EkhNZUzRtCemO0BSSusqFtKWouNa2gxlS7H2dxUdlKKPc23ySeJLfUbK4itLa2RKGpnG6pSqlSKL7YnAhCsoLPrWyx8iaRiWcYw0eyWTzdKuYXQhSLKU1WK8VisnoFNeHB8NSZeHq7nUhc6NpZMol5RSYK8s@/nz6jIhrVfmKantZ5ptgsWZ3WFSDV3gSGpcyNuHqoQ2KCX47iMQ4guulWpoIEOiEo5ZIA6ctyEmkRUg94v3werJWErwXDkpFfEquI/KNzSqmQlHBLf9vut@nDO@zlIiTyzpHnePSGjt0G2@RIynArkRNktekz9Qy113TwO5d0/BokPa4JhfGJDKVYjkQaPrN5xD/5UfWtqHFC2scPGtuOhB/i9JZ8uD6EwIkdz4BJGEkHh9Izy9X6YSwn@tSTHuq4D64buO3ys7HS3hS/5G7YVvVSfC5e0SlxPE2LCjhgMNTqDTBpPZag1JmWvKBytRuNers@0kdjbwYiDdVFIwwMQyvbYRwSD@YEZxPa9R0obqZqoZoqHa2xaXQaafRQscZOfedyUqkA7FVVr9OnmoUoHmbasuoTKs@R7uA5moPDWJ/peGClO3zZ2kPAXajayyux4TCrGubiwOX1Ex6NoAxdYoZ8j3Y9c1Ud1Jvo/hYfNVEQTkWx@fY00oAuVZ1Ftbo76fAPl2U6IAsVqlNwU4q56pB16p0X06pTHwMHz6omVNaCZMK0KsG/NWF0bEvt@nRe7Gy9qWZV3AaVVjPltKrAkAhDJUDDXQR7Dm4FbvBXUH5JmAmBMSGdmWYkJa3oStqz9yyo5UylgpUNzURWeGvJlLppJno202oiNRr00CplUUsP2dhIDxMQ6qmumRw8KSbE11uFVC6XTFZfQ@6cWKIn7SS3ctVeYoe1k@AAAzvcKivkqv164kWymthI1l39dXWxyRPJSAM7OZV4vAGV6wtl7mTUzLCNgpK@FNvilam5XkwpqpXmJNYUFShe5u2gJnzVEE6h7q8YiBJscfUEmIYquAVdmrMZc0Zh7jZGltHUoamUslr1QSJjn7wkhAR@uZZvs0zE40U1Hk/Gqyj@b4C7T56IlsSBsMXvKVsCMCpCRSirIOstkKUbWeDLawUQw64iPcMds1w5Er2MXF1e1RZ3jnyDzWZaSgys9xgbpGIRJtO6sdSOsg0yiVKD5mi269uDp9tVH3p7NxKt0Dap@Z4W1vKPpIryxscuVqdqjRf83cJdGpBqhFSnNNmpvzqvZqHMvQU7lM@9jPBa5ZsX5FqqIbcigkA9lS/ElfJJnlP2Lkp6y9nuZfBN9spjlKRZQqvwHtg8Tb57YpiXpazYIAkwwaLvUlAjuOOrIb@LAkG/oor291VdXo4vL0HCvcJj1mo2H4ladrDlCuRKDygdjAT5vIAzIjobH5dfFF@UXjx@dvjscJ/dz1RKldKidNC6n04rcSVeY/eBATWe7oHk8ZbZeeWd9TltNotWo5VxPJuLZ5eC1aPTei5YWE0ojYao1FS2BbjKKkBv@kpBzLxtcMRrkEdBBZ/3v/Hj3LRWArsKTF4F6jSfUhsNZVNNRsfvv/43eHzpcu@L7UcsjgX82z/7mVr82z/757S8F7@q8kIXowCJRqVQjJ5GeRZyRZYEC18zVqIN2XdXikoy6orcBtnLR923viKJhJopgd/uIbcJBai1aDkaiZYev3zLWA1EwEZvMDBUMsnyklgVq4AoBX/2DmeR3okbL4GWuG5Mxm1@ZQQOZj42G43GJu3@izdSeOJOzdOMe/OqesrnClCC2LTop7ub@NNfhA6brgv2wAbWzZrO8g2Fgcghy@9/43dVtfC3f/bbreTb9tv2N4GklsvlgqJGf3Xzivr6XFTIi27xLaAVPLsqlvhedqTOr1z@SengHB99Thh4W93R8Pwjqm83DesMAuB4Dmb8UCUwABV2x0ODEX8EfoOnWHxzR3P1Qi6wuTP89DxN2uEhPrciywPDG046dGrvxJkdeId0pkEGfDFAXidzx7Q78kjDeQL6OpEL4g9AoDLriSXDqIdHEujrjchxomaGNqnMgaL12gDWxmIlkpUIg5THeLq4Ne33BTqWrJu9Y32sOagkBfyDs5sHPQRDxTl06Dk4b7vED4WHbanGdRbf5RvPRTo1bRPv4caDw3ZUtYw0Ouh4FELAc7/@ER7aUy5IaMMP8grBfnKA6NuobTOA5x9cDwOEn/Cdh8AyotIRnw@oL5aIpaj8qSATOK3LHSgfc6uf6NyBEqLcOMxIa86AFENZqFYH0kpAs0qoRbCpVE7TnE@sK1TfdLzbYLU6A9YblZhQSbBCSZ9i33CA9VJKC@pNiPGikIvlSNX9nAAgbxA8zowakXCHvt15RVqAfE0LiH9S4OefcEe1S/wD9h6zfF2i7KJjeAQAQxsBYEh5gGdfeBWll1C1MxngoQLsC5LtDGTDdSd6vljKUYY0PKQcgAI/ugSqyr6SY5kyh2eCw1KUvSEz9XPdpFP3frZRm5zGOyXhGe5eQUV5yGAXkoQ6UJVLJYVaSJTT3O3B3v6j7ZO9B2kmKnkEx5NdXTuETSxULvdOkX/fnLhDH40wCO@@UqeQ40iecNPx@3I86Wf9/mK1pxYzHESA3yPCSb1xIl6nYI4@wo8/8YjZWOshrUpTGCvuH1zHE@P8dJThYlYmjol4E1Ru0POjUQFRGtOKIgoufYAcwmDBfN4GbEB4bgCtpRVQAz51a4PgMUa1HIS5wqoT3kBYRbHB9Q4IuyZ@DS6OWp4WqW2c@o7G4ieohRqGdCJtG3GiC6jZYFiPf@rGq13gzQOegp0nJslLvwSG1cdcJHjFndg7s6D9EhP/3IkAFZIEnjgZHkT5xZ/Hgc8I43PNhJe8PNcc9qYOGEo9TuJEfc@k832JOFdICsHeSMhz@Oe96l41DNCxezMJtalZvd2hYfYSbxbTGAOrafQTqVS3Xs8mLyFJZwzEyR0DMdRRXktW0a2/5BZ@QF1utSzIn7Rp6Rfsy8ePHkKTP9XpOHfzxelmTE4Da5usYhG0egKBHhw@PtIcV3eS0hjf@6EQlMDvN/iJSNDaI7eZOaXcpwUsmoy9ECjnQPf80rs7sxNt8EQb6Ym4FucHqTApAxrFqGkSF4KqRiqVhCJqTeN0qY7qwnLjCsnLQZ2gho7er3agos@qV279PDFIVj14DReTyEMSdVWl2D0IVHfhca3WDfya88OTx4/q8ZrGMNb6il4RT3VC5ABEIYShE@LbjqPNllAHqAphlcfPQhLCwJWKC43lstRkrREHlnVtfh7ZpLxBkqT4HIF7iUnaxzinfrNJq84cC2ZjvY4OfGj7bO9ESENYZ6In0dHC4W1GRIsf868HaXB0Q0pBQ@DsGGHq9dy9e@TGtXvU62omkwTUrF5BbC5gbiIUe5zqlaPVe4mwIrWxsUKlgCqpsma5F6iEGVjeTL64ZTswRNR7wEPec4GE1FHR8Lnhze65gG31QD3BPX7Osr6R2ywdGjvf/LJ8XHiQ6HY@V4S08Mq1LRDRnPFiBhztQuJsEdBYp8uxizKB6ha7mjzWzmw518t0S5mSUuzpxbxeymRL3byeLXeAS@z2c6VOr1zUivluR4bBzaMg0sjA7wUJHP0x2f7dkl3HmJVAxu/3FeDWe/lyv6xmstlcp5TvZXK5fknRstlCTy11yp3bubZ5flDcCugujh3XKfCn65m7yA3a7odO/g8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&  xxxxx  \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v+] >>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._Vd 2=>+[u ];5#>E >
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

When Re:direction queue is empty `+` command (`♦`) gives `queue underflow` error. So to add Re:direction `+` on line 1 needs to be evaded. 
This is done by replacing Surface `o` with `v`. Also, Surface `e` is replaced with `>`. So MiLambda code ends up on line 4. 
First `v` on line 1 turns down only 3 2D langs: Surface, MiLambda and Re:direction.

Some random selection of 2D langs that I thought might be affected by `v` (but are not):

- [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony#special-characters) – no string mode, `v` will just set the current memory cell to its ASCII code.
- [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice#string-mode)  –  has impure string mode, in string mode `v` doesn't work (but mirrors do work).
- [axo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/axo) – has impure string mode, `v` is not a command (in all modes), `%` is used instead.
- [PingPong](https://web.archive.org/web/20050306053646fw_/http://www.inz.info:80/pingpong/Ref.html)  –  no string mode, `v` is not a command.

This is how Re:direction is executed in the polyglot:

```
line 1    v
line 4    > +
line 5     v+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
line 6    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
line 7    >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>       v
line 9                                                              >
```

Two pluses repeat two previously executed commands (`v` and `>`). Execution wraps on both axes.

Fixed Chip by adding `:` on line 7. `<` on line 4 is for Minimal-2D. `5` → `7` on line 1 is for Delimit.

Answer (score 6):

## 244. [bosh](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html), 11350 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEUCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZJkEQLBNgAKJGtVtfMJDXXE7tynclc13h84zMziRM7SVV8UzfXk4pdrvJ8TbnyyT@gnS8pV8rzDyZrrQ2ApESq1ROnKiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FjqaO/zVr6J4sSPbnA1M22Oe7nqs5xjnuiOxnRm7rxluXs1GIgi17QwmI93y3EokyhTGLP2CHVhdowduzLPPdMt4ozvgpzI2duyBo42YN9Q8sBgQij3Qzbejtx7r2qORZvVcgMwydqSBZ3/SPWNax/UcresZtgVeOcaeWaY26vQ0BhC6M3Z0j6LPM4iie0Zhln0KjD22HVfH5Lu669roWGSspo/G3qwBlhJAaI5hP9p@8tm1wGXGPtMgZ2NTn17Li5Jhzw3d6V0LoSjsi5P9/euuKvuGaFts/2b@lCx75riaqV2PP8e2J5594F13z7PtgW5pTJXKknrds8B2HO1GkCJzdK3XN0xdMqwuE9lQN8e6w9CF9W0HmszTzVKmlGlvz0NKXQxbmntei7YeXExzBi542uc6GHVoibGh91jfsUdMs9wLSEkpZ@bwGG15GR26kEFANPbKhdA9nbmWMR7rHveE4uoOeUPKzDSsswjHviPH7k26hjUAOB3qdTzxqExupAvBGmzs47CEBhalWuBgkIVje6QvtoULyAu5dsd61@gbXV45@tTTLRfK60rMgLa7MEyT9XQTAsxj76aZa7OJu@DUMbWh1JUiWLmYChudmcxg3fGYcS8oBmRpP1Ni@sh@ZbA34G8OXTYdj5hrjMDb69r9vq6zN/p4CMEjPTvC4OqOrxUrtMV0gLF0KNru0beg0jysS6sP@eqxzgIcZIIyTMXVLBvqzmGWNuKo0B3PqOgQTRiib9sSuvds3bXiHruwnTPW0bsalhkTc/VBX5uYkKLRx7YAJDBcNrLhDS1oMcgWBPawIjBuTCyysiCYTNC2@hh6JbatjbgCDR008YWjAXI4rt@InjEC1DC8uMt0zTWQXEEQV7d6hBbjkJDZUNrFFmfnBvQ6qIqJQ3G7ukN4T/EyLAVEqYWImrhwDA/QAUuxzY50zWEnjq4nOZLqblcbI4ouJgmJ2ZiChwWRCCtrtfje4X4csJOHkLQxYKOTPfnm5xGNSXUWa1fhrgtCNbL35AG7jLXQzAkmYPDYSWhJVn/HXLnV0uGeKh154FxFINYI1IrJZHvsyZo4hgyKHmRQ1tCIJvFclcbmQsKsdq0NFvoMh@pBawAFYF@kqWTdieMgaZ9XqnYGhTZtawD1CYV1JhZv8kIGmgDwr@emmX6uIw7wNrIvqIZPhoAh8AfQBbLCRxuqUBhvoB/6NRqk69rmhOAgpOthZ4RagaAY40GffcH6mmFiEPDHqHiuHd0F5MQwE6uHLT8yLL0nsSAbRHIc6IjnkJwGkZID9IbRAmGhTAEwNIRNRUWv97/9e73BAOLZ7nZtp@ej6xeA7F0aFzXKLIxsDBHWtjSTsgVwaUydB4cEzjXT6BGJ06yZnwRlglK9sCdmj1FHvTCgyw01oLQ6UIeup3Mktyce5DHNRtoZJ4cGx1wo@EjrQMNSApQ2FVtk93ehlbrQzQlnxNHE65eYON5jcVd@kdiqJLY2WjpkLiklN2OyPKgCwkmb5AS2@G2Y88X20jjhepprG73IeOYNbUtlYpcJ3bo91q1EfCmOeDrudOJJCcl0Ilk16l2pb1i9RLwGuNiAhOPJarfebRqV0@q14ItJQjQXGA12Vz3RTQpIaqhTnMsj4CwkoGRfiL5pwc9221jl6C0tOGPFXHc75w5R4lsQL21EEKBDkmvq@jiRkZQkkgmEW1lu9FhV0mtx@AWuGKepeDSeWiw6xQAlXSoodtYTw0ayZY6HyGxApVjuGGiug7jb1QB7XBzRPODn0qxDeE3DIFAWookXehyodgcIaYBH1CV5l8PwIhJKP4Z5F1ruyXpvoSMDEYC@7Lk3qLFpI2tAecKRB0iHhYlqA2gaCMwLss0LwlMil@UinVlAUDC2js5KYseAToDdDWi6j/MLZQPwrMphIDbeSRZoz0ib4ajG@YJ5h8ExTWMjIA/OjHV1pDlAfHQ@oGAiE@p/LjC9zO6zjKjm88t97EYX8xx5W/wKiPQb@daehIVf7ExIaFgfeGxTswYTbQD0wrYgiNbt6mPPJ1RQEtcDUnR9vCFH0R88JXcYid2/njYNIgFvNE8DiTxvPX8o1JC6@Dy7CAwZ8n1cEGA9wwGyBCP5tdQB4Pxa4sJLBFnKwEthTRYCDgCQTJ/q3YkHVA0Q@GJodIeAs5g7i9NFPghdTx6cFlMHyi72w6QxM0rjnhqR5NAJs7E2ChFb9GY8MLhiVI0lB2r8RYfbY9bc0YqI7TCLMBAsuEqyJgHufSDOkW3ZKyKFigyjRZBlH94OwIkdI0cMA1fAdlFnDdnksImgzYBqQM8H/Bt63titwDhheMNJRwJMkU@c2YF3aCGyyJ4zMzybmzum3QGy7EL/lIMU5O6kY0yvFYjcwjZ85UbOgQHru6wOI/frCWBdIt53gWCS@y4CL3gJRLgpCv4UAJCAJKioRN8lUrwPROV4ZnUTwhJSCmkmYN8VkmDAgGHVfI7M23I2X4HT9Vwi2GJmJBmhZNfpkkFc4EkxegSnbEU@WSraHfMY@UQQ4NHXTFeHtzUxTbROLE7lEpxXSLLLyCefAGlLUHLGaGwaXcNrc192757PU7ANEPCQbeojz5SEMJ/4krQEBAVg/OGHQ0uefUzMbiIJBfnkailh3XFsh6frDR37gpEDgkUWK3XXHiF1Z8@J4UIOGmRaw0LZ3h9LaSjVVrIQ4ZhK/HI8Lr2yDStxGd/Y2IhX4g0YMTc2tsBUQ9MWmlJg2iKTSCaEk9BEIdJkQt8mhUC30/hVM4h5mjzF7jDF0f6NMU5ozUole5rWmor/VvGdhHqGEQOgRXxBPPFkvY7GZFJoXEBBpU5/ufS7OOoddx1j7FfC59q5xu1@LWSpGqDhbAcFgyoyL7fXyajuAHcBwkB3mHDirWamddq6bPVSrat4GkMnq1q9A4WC9BIjaeDYE2BDks1cRVROk8lmFpiPTj2eiW8mEiURxDiQRJKflpIpjdd2Iq7DaJhoteJQqX79NLtDh@KbptVkMqwqyAcyPMBrJ@LSZQnS7yRPk6k4hE3G0yC61eNxqJkuVoJLhca@tFRBh0@/wStmN5WKUPcGqRTvG8MpuKHQuxz8aPLmDdIuHkcnxDBzonEub@wDyAdWACuh5zWhNfDq9BnS0aU0PrP7XCraxcfeo/2IPqXW@uxwf@9pnZIZau4Z8BTiAGFl4JWhVpyeBNTAnPT0yCoYIBtg6s5zghMHmPig22WizQhM7PJMLAwXXbYmNqA1xHjaTDRHy0Vwh5Df3aUyUCTkTiFv41@6QZY4@Mo8hUnuA8XePX60ND82OgN@gnVdE5lv0eEFAKu8yR179ApljAo7IBnNAgYTcAv4y144F2DZloi0MBDn7MWE@IQIQJAbclvISRhLMBhx35iCSBzF@RSf9UeOFbn/XdsC4VSXnhM1FBgQcpyq0qWV/P8RZ6SkrjvvncDpg3Fsal2g98vRtQTWggiBAsnyap9k9UbE14UDkuM/VEZgpbqahfXXM0hOnRjuEKsXZAkcBZw@1CoKqTi5Q7V2wLrA5Q6gpvWp4XGpFXr4MQZ5qLmJJMpJ21zOQCxDHhkzFUzbEQNrd0HC14FXRl8@XcL2rHPDsS2sZGkPogZSVMU2uBb5quoFNNrePlAfrK/fVZFDjd1wVhbqdjHW65XbdaF3WbZpD2y2CQCImpLEEfvAwulNkHI8bQw9ynhDFbQ9sEHUX8ZBXQ8nTAvZUN7UEFImeOkVjAJsdaHnAGvKfHzw1R6wIUo@k4H8B7YMXWEhF2K5XkZ07LI5gL8EYCLeYEt@pY@HM2cJnVzbnzfxaPKQOiafydKAhYRc@T38DQVd7OTcBfp54NULTKvKvkcyAU7eLcrVS6Vf4lZ4t4ESRq85o2tQFUuR3mjwefsi4WrJS3QrnCoQ@yPb0@QvJCDR@IgghywaTHDl@EZcFkV8CuTF1AaTe/q5jFRqHvN0T@@ujHuq610ZfXFwY4FhZfUEnmuqpgWXRQ8oJn8HdRCGvF7@QSqFhJ1yF6bNMw2D/Mlwokf07tBmQgtEjMWSCTBADEFWFqHmgQFEuSQM5i8HRTx7AmJdTzeNkeEd0IS9aaHsIhHxlpBq@b67QG/mERwZOjDkfMJhPsjgpPp8jLIGHP4pUHKKFUR8iVepo/fkzXlsj23bAbnSZQrNKahh1Y98D9l2xz3Jm0IEPNQeje9uMM4/OXyw1z7aPnlYlyeuI5tGB2hET2@PQJg1oTusuTBvOEO4B7hjWPbIgBIFUb45M5/atseZB1w1uNsVxYBBHI8etB8d7DzdfvotP3M0ohujialhHiuxawBhHMcEc2s0XbtjA29hTdbGBMzF4c7hoyCWz589OthuP9g7OjxZiObVxDQ0ZSqPzwbrCvQ5gjBFyvCqPzR7y8s5JKYuzSL4xAZlrioD2ZSJIjxFdOOJolQmoQeyyDg8iiLOAms4z@0wVcmUy72OVirphV43lyv2tX6vl1OVUr5fyqv5DDyKhbLO3hK4KOpTmrkBE58VwQkkTAMyTy9FygUcDoiiXeBYZivzFfrekrluPq8Xc2Wt3C2Xy5pa7GU1tVTU9UKxn8tk9IKS6XdKSil7a@YWsoGs1dw2ohkg6HU4WUCeQPwS8FrqDjzzwOtdsJ6qqoVuvl/Oqr18JtfrlDP5Uq@jFLVOWc/0c1lFVXpdVakEYXFGFajEEBoMuUoLWNPAS1TAMxkJBtPFJqYlxmAN2ic4sSySmHGwhoyCg@@RQ4@Jv4KMU7O@ex7dg/VjnKLx3QvoPsLV4zknS9bQ0QcsESAuIktOJ3Aso2O4fLy0sAqk0qefq/zXB/JjvlQyVxj5BS5AL5TvUlHI/dzr95ecVXI@E3EoM@fOWXLmy8/LC79@YW94rQQO48tRfHzZemV8N7xWAofx5Xl8uNy9OrprPqtAw8gKFBkuj6@M65rHCsAwpiLFtLikPvcrkd@69XQ/rZXeawOFcZcpbr5U3n7FVyva/ko5YjPvICfAiT2ygX9@ZOC8fX@px0RCCbwVEYJphOWJpLmPOl8mYeL56vUdYTEiTgwM68wmwTk0tTOSksdYwihGZ@bNkH0QNeixBHojUzd9@Pg16vTpsQIAB93rM3PkQdOe/tAPQ60mP6UXToCuysHyVO5S8h29PwEpSO4YFpo/ACaWSwTZ73SMdaBQE7jzIHivAKuwpxOQRFUpJymB2ItLJ0Cz@TzsycEhAXY0EuKW5//ZUuV7E8eDUP77P3@7B41ws4mG2oxkwdDQtvQLwo/@2hbzg6KFHqtbdz7qU8WQ6UNRdjVcctXM0LA6amp9URxqzghFLr@5AUHxAZhwC67xnPO5mOC9OpEKo0peXmdgljFi3RXQBHttSYQnRkK2aWs9qgYuChs6BXKwsXkz6FMuFC4wPDDyrEtoxcoFm28V8IYTb8KfuDvgQ81ojPG@rYv6kJm81lF0YJG1jqHf0uiOdjbp2SJwelRkzFhhBey89DRZJ/ZN7Ywb22hcXXxeQMcYDICf8N/rwC6GINuQUCpf0OtDeOFaE3csdqCxPOg4ZKOuMLolBcfkz3Ughr95LjSsrzXDpMcdGj1ELkIXYOmoonE/k7hQaca1aja1zgxF9eHHYxkmSAwO0Jx6N5XKZHHYC9d@F7cirQ@PYyWFL5dXh@Y7qXiVrBKvZL6DSuQTyFRmf0/VBxoWBi5jpJmi2lswrqXowdTx3LQClOZtxK6puYBant8c@jk0Hz1uQ3ccmbogdjlz0y3IPs9OsAVg3WqyT7b8Xt21TcPFrm2uo6DXF@DmaeJeNnosTEkbqyq2RzyTOxRD02q6YHc9XMpdg2h3oHJ8FRXXqRcwR7LXVVrXvsB7LWsxtM91/lw90L1Zmas7UCzRJJQwuitHlF73Q5iK24Hosboez1bmy@uaK92X@0AwxbEooN0Rr13DtF12TM/bqmXgQDD@XI3RizVoaJZI60GL5tXB/EyNmeTPsq5pV80c2GahNJA1eKxt/InTxzHBf9@V@oXUS1E@TL0C/si2FP@9luyfyc7Zh9qOliYcXLRfMN4yAq8iYf6i5PoCgiSBO3FWF24/U6KQkszl5XUN4HSHF9oseP8aI8u62g1GlvGM@G1g/zBAuQQGz@E8@K@TWu721Hp3I083oi1@qBALjXtm6jCQ0fNGkzI1o3xkCCWTuTux6psTfaKvpFWHnVc6bm6/RQq5e6YyfjFi/mwnzgjhXGcI9caXH@@UaxzD0XYrgdFMAzr5BzmdlfRuDDz6GEXuIzAcoeFmwIE1GS817pIUZz29veaG46Bn272lTKLPx1Kk0of5qSVG3tXpvlW44sIgrm3Vs5lMxudvFuavlyy3CV3ZMOwrgz@XEiaXecpzWJwNcRaMq9OYT6VC0xtnroiTmnejTuq6GQECLpdly7B0b4bPdU2yitp2bNv8mCYEotszkH8DrhQXfj7UlDd4I383GJvPfbg4c9Lpr5v14AOSL51C7aHgfRs2LE693qmZRVyyhl46uGa9fR5oYSL3Q6nAME@TS3zrhLme8fRnVBSpJBVv7ZGcnbU7uqnx17SQuy2@spS9Nb6QZfH5ZFrbwvUwvgI2X1GNXqNb4xlUltEDIWeoj3Sy3iIdaL1XEzd4rQWa2niv8JZovXFduLEBhMLC59Jq2wIr5dkWiGWe5gx0lGtMXBX3XdcR52BWfWXlHoy0gc4PVd1GPedTHbh1mEuDc@PqSY8K33XWhWB868ftqACd6UyfucF7ZYSPZ11oz8now1N11/p9lzYqfaijS/LKxYQP8IrW0B5aQ33IdwKFtnXdAzDS48fhbisE5N/fZcSIRi3uVFqsXdM2zbvULtJITjFtu78yX3t4UKsHQT8q3pnWAQ//9cFpQBjvqZJo4F/Xd4b6BIYt1/bssS6SbR2oiRNG/LmOkgYLPL/uTNStswRQI8H7143/g/LpQLO98Zhe7bE5celBQUU6X7eqKfcpmbtgheHxrUccd/WB3ekOjQ9lqaNrnmWcycGsELfeKt2OF2rBYOIDdJZMAyrPmUmIDfVF/2N8HaxrUn@CiQ9doWF1G1fY7sRxZlgTnm0z17Qv5jRieQ9FOJXLVyDQsC4H/urgCm/iCHB3XbCL7JZlEH8xcS2CESOOTLeoZ4BpUdbOKi1t8VzoHdksf6zjja6VnzK1sIb7MdOi/tYHmiA0FmZvwX0Jf5YWpFcOWNZwMnBvkjs@ad8DNgsfK1t6e4CHmq81NG9UGIU0y3@tq2/VlHELN7zb0HIT/dYVlvytSywEp5iiZhvwasML2nCydurMNMYufzKxr65kGm4uI9@Emq0Wnf326el9vh6Cpg9xeyPbwYNEwFaIXUd3uzidjhSZ81Cc@lj2ACizaLI5cAC7sgg3V65XN//iqCd@@UQfaLjN8pGBOy7NFZgBMV9fxL5LxN@caK7xzYnt6SvjvL6YfZcoH2sDo/twqRWCCIPa9ffk8ddSF0Cnmw1xMTRcOs8RGG6Zg0KE4yiMONcG/n@V9HZt@j48JX37NMsC4@TvBWfiAQv2jIcGXEBAf21lWqtm5u0xyZEzMt02KW94NFPrv1di2OpNAbclfzEZjSeu/1qdOu3bWZyyHp2Ru3thAIkUXwNlZkPN9FZPay/M1AL/5Q@Yc@M6rvwrw7QH7KtShgG7BgM4MulrkG4Hhu8jzYPeYa1AZEr/jounOBEiOrxwrwEv9CwTDcvwbp/08TwN5KbgjQXigw@eTJQf4VO6/7ExiCera@XRrRwNjPWzrokH5T9WOuBkGDDxmA6yozE8S7@I@34y@q4fYTDaWPrFogx360JQBYdY25p4Iu78v22MKdw6xlTYtFRYQA@W@Obe42fJAEsGwy7fEvshvlQH4XDimrO5ae1mhBXIZ1jAwK2nzTdDBFLGA53UHTylTZx3CLc9xtNVNBQ8sFdJQ0czGJk@SqSCwWUyeqB3cXXyTnl4Yj8G9g6GuzEQ49FTHbcWXKMx6wNj0Ed2VzOhznp3Su6Yol8xlsyFcW2sd6DtzblpNd@2LvIHmqet4bVospEkxtD0QVwyzI7uvKJZxAXzOkH4ZqYe6lMSXdYjFO@potftciYdp/OW@tGCNF9hx2Obn7q@BSdCMgSDBz3uvj4v4W7npbFxpTh3s5yH53yDit7jR/3WFdTRO7bJnzjSrCEWlsG3I2iOobvyI8OaTMmNicDprRaK@MbfjFTEiRF3CF3wwgCJPNwPjNvb@OZi95rcBQz0uebSJoHVEtDS3uO770Maak7XxtU23/CRa20Lh8g@QOXDzdV8M0MHEGgK5E7rTgJNBB/IqjnqjOixXoJZbu2negcP6nXo1KmnTVexm8sHznzHa0e@AkKH3b/AEkcgJyU/PNRdF/KWa90Y04NI/sVKVAmSe2Lo3Tda8q69iWagZY1k4JUdannrHDBDpi56Q9yZKXveOpLxxDib9O6wQhYsu0xGOq50L6/3rEUs2x0SVtir1/ZDsuvo/oZv3FsIJCAwI@0Vt9eiLUYP/8Odz2UYutuFHJ77n0zFARCzVSn6ZyxIHUyoOMBN@6d/wM1w/BPGrhToNorSSSlC42DPPouicoMJyuee7UiM4BIJLZVKJiM8EO6fGFgAFkCRchZU3MD1vrgMGBqPYI0@azZZ7HJayVSUK1ZnQkVgp6c8VrxIjcDedEyaVZ7y4M2YdlqPxUUxHou3rArLxENw3QRmfiW4tgTbN@jF8zuvAq51ySaVSWGJq1wxBXQfVPoy1KyeqbNnFi1qAfflcPUKXHfHCW7W/MUf9nxdOKTzaWSAsA0Vgrqs7JE@tC@2eLp@6sCLaKhLB@MAuczkmh3E3W0GQoHXHXIVOPYFe7Z/UvIVa/iKs8ByxKdZwlzwxsX1Hjwk6PHG47kJD3z5CYehgkIBpzkZWUC8e97QldixQef/Js58R7@vTszyHJzQ7aXZAevpuC@OjnXSGoZp22d01ANz8os/5OpE6HCnf@guSJ7UCC2kiGc4FdLh0e3aE8h1EMkb3bF9kARWMkhiE1wxJC1W5J7EI4@k5wQwUgy0fFAyXNXH7vYxE/dYHPVj4an8qtFPxLaffvZFM3Naf8dGsv6fvy0nL/2KEz4VywVXSLMApHqFiLXonQfvuW@cCbGpwBMMT74aPv94wdsDdXtxJMPDrwGO2fbY7zWkqYkUE4XY6B/4T6CZ2jlQ9zEiJU@EsPoFqfugI1YWkg1SMuZCBwNrkqLmva4eS0z4IpZ47LE8JIgqUzQwcbVQdBYUVVdgkNiUvWVDRDLgQZR8Bmy8Ik3UljKq7wS7prOLu9nlB3pnQjs6z1VJzdepOLF2vdYgE9A2G7UWNV@0pmpGbE2Le6eyG1RqqzX9NKN@CbVuOxDqnow9b@/Jg8uY1Mi8fetqMyYIV/Eq330PZCJ2eXRwtHd8sn3y7Bha4SogP/v8DE5AaxCL6Fjd0DZJHxTUC7I2H0F/QhtqZ0iwmMZqqG4wmYwsHoAiUL@uBVGIceMCaVoK/YHgq8K7@oL/TQCfpvUNFmDUAQxp2IaAbFhrWPjJGLVaMT@sr5mHsMxAGo8dKKwYPOOwgpZSVQmsDpUlQmXdsarY@sJucbe71NgHY7m92rZWgmCNhek1Q39exJVVcPV3Uu4xDJT/8@XmsdxeboK5pdwAGroGYfa3Dx49e7q3HAxwjN5EdevlvH/yjxNn7GmcNQpUEdGBez8gLgDWBSZQAG71BzOuEFH3LnQolk8cuyMemDCU8i9E5ogJNVNHhZynVV4XiQTlAHmQKhbr2sHEvjFdyGIwRi9Ed8mLGBKBfSGMOsi4JPgxR0mxpIRXUAyM1a@uoOsdERH36XXcXWR/0kGPw6LhGD1xeZ9bM1SFo47L4L8wKgUm9ZRNmT@cKadMZCrcpm4NoMABbLLKxygW4xUhxHjehTC/qBMQ8tR7pdGcO2249w/0wShtamNUQOZDP7E9vcJeT2xSGhAQk5C/IHWUGtffSU3LFVOSMgIQWYDTDsYtiu9g/7iO3BlnzYi@L@LcxMKBCoC4Nk3/WK/noMpZft6Sq7XjVW77GtSCoZIkUdfXmBRyCS47N1wDZChqhD7yOCZQSiyNX3BUx0rqIti26QJP0oPhGzgUD4daYE4kOgXGj4KJFhOigJNSyDKmmRBBWLd@U6MWDKUXICV2X/LAMYKjmN2FOOO1DVGEmhuA6OyfKKugMlYSwCrMcya4yasRvxEkyEKFTOLQG5kLgCt0C7Z0@f1v/x7XJ9jywPx93zzN7IDtN31bH8y/FfgoCtj@SWhTwfYDbnshY5PdVKLmJ@/P76w9Mgd4eV@4USakCYECWipL2NrY0l8cHDG3i6pNsS1HIBHPmwkpDOIcSEaAfyNAinNqYwTnKcybcB5PovkFoAjgFeAHsjfI0VB6unOaQFVaFVnGjOPMu0Qb7fQpX/gmzVqvJ6hREpgwuZAv5BQZMimeBxGSso8BnvvhESaTFaCJkXNjXH/Z6bJarcYEt6uZer1Q5bghx7QXWeFlmNEYwEa4oNBkEAaCzEOAX8MPlohpKSWJQXEgiytxpGk9m6MacIMJMgBIEp2tQD0AsJu2X1WAx5Y@9YhjmgUCEBBsy15QJRtEJEJEPG7Ue3i9O87P8uBk0EIHlRabQXiOYMcIVhFWIWvzBWt5LevU13/JAPF@sgJ1LTD/oxVKMTlmofqTm9oYE9d1KWJp2P1jy8Y5tX3ILUuospqVlUJyAUMFPyrIL3b1txAldG4gFl3deGWP3e3dvYPPD4@Ob2jlIcj4dbA4izdqqZYopZunoSEe5nu5Unf25ePHO/tBVS7maj6rhRDzjY3Xs7kqtes5XZP6c35s6mba5HEjISVz14hpx5C4TxuEb8Y@95UXAHf5qY0bqSaSl1fN01qjZUVvJP92labVqLSJyAWmlkt6VuPXs4lZDFWqn6BKdVcKzgQreCAYT4p59tn8eLHvsODBwYNYgAJEJDmAWoGxQQYO@fzMXA@GynW6u0T6@BwO6b8Mc7QAeRJof8euNVfb5usrG2ru0DQ6ERi7e6jDj2sbCdRphHpKJHdsGl4iGaHZjzpyQEDEEr4O@GllKtFSXYK0rVJcaXabCrQgvmQEOgHEFz@auEN2ZI/ZfOrpgR6YngIjwh5M@NqNzj6fjACuT6@nOpJYHVgTEQJDRcXDrHKBGnqWrwFtmkItc5BeE/Wg@QWXRr18YpqUhvq0ZwyAgCeSaejpnyrAUYVntLHQpBXNigON4zX8GZ6WWazSj1KEN51HrjU1ybB6@jSBml0qp8Caonv84vl5PCncwAHSxrcb6O@6ppYv6Iia5/eIuUq7a52tHCp@v6Y3sVxG7Th43ByaBVI89pxHYITxKdEfaWOWmJC@SJdJjKyJVsJKu56TZGKDq5ywWCpFAjW8yAMYZgTtk4kQhyVQvXJCrkProKtr9fD1xhizpiJJp2CmRJIshpNpuzCU4zRUMgICEgSpULR1bFtWwRxx7JU45kEY9I@QAiuGShNXeJOaQ1zehH4KdUGlZo17C4p/5j2Q12q5XPFbY5nUlBmgxU0qL8kQ7QoSEjCoUL/@6WGoNVQDjvricRoYyML9b@iWpUMFAc6MNBiDtQkgmZNMBx99SM/VRlMKUZ7Fh/5xZMjosjrpvfiliauGMblK8zLVKxhTX7ZwUO37w@pM/vuyJFcvEzGzPpOB0Uk2ErFhXUllN1OpmLWZiFk41N@7h9M5VzHgJNoSSEdTABJjZrIK@AycRz1mVWNaLRHr1dVNCgFWkM8uIcA7V5YuY9qVHLsHI3UaXBzeeRMxlzQSZiRJuYL8YQ@JyWnAmUtU4EZffMDkY0YqhXmQYm3MwDu5dZwimt06lmnmqOozovJg5He3a1Q1bIkb37vgFeg7@w0NhF1Fwu7vAm8HwHNl0tlVfmt4D57wN/CgDaN9fbq7yPkLyz53Jyw@vYuTsiiu/5GrhIQKnCagEtGa1pJJICa/@lVUKTAhEdsqZM9T8XymCg@lWmR59mmspeaiLHofJHV5U3CEy9aD0jnT@2rhtSg2tb70@vTo7Ojoy2QrEY/uHr4QlByAFlmZ7rteRaauudjHXdHophyJypvKvaIsv3z5EthduJoNqbEIJZ0mm2L8tJkogqVRLG6mC6XN9P14m7KSTKhq8pgZhsxaxtjt9eC2h/TdlUSUX2xrC9MCA/yZ7zaa9rnbPDMcxHcNwgZeH4KraPkoaxU1bTOVU@9bVUnNqL/4@cZV@vKoXfvFd0ayvoGvQ3x9/@oxmo@V/KcbG5/u7ORyaag8bj766uhb29vbuQfp/FEzv5UTMxu1v/izjQ1VranyxqnrKqfx5tmXgprJCdIvfhY/Ovpm23Wx/fDKMgWM@CzBrbB8np2xN3Cd9Rn@yfymt2DW0Nzpv8EBEpjlOhGbeDyfjR@/iGNx30QVRYnO6NemathgSmOr@F9@ePg66kUbqvzcgbcXfR0tlKLcCAawZQPbebQRrSFY4So6k@v1OhiL/@XfQfjG5xAP@sxq8Gjkg7gKs2hDrFOQt9FGAQyKqkK6/@3b345EG1NEhMbBPlMb6ibHFaV0T7nH2BQvxlpRpZQ7vA/OwcV9Fi4mK4raCtpzobmxaUPnIRQe2pXZC25huweYEWU@NpDhY@DwEz2FjfsvH7BaA4ZavCqV@yGqyaxYEmwbunMVbI9C96eSCJfUDuxVtIp@EaKlerrNkw9xNbpguFbg8Mn8sof2j4Tbw@sv/7@//NFf/pB@P6L7P0WiwWq62DxPnUK78YsJDaRPvp09tthjflkW/OEOrOiCDmCy2Lws0WijgQ/6@zYy0fuam@/TCC0EMQ/yYThKNxJ9B22C2MfOG0sXa8jzklEReK7J8HihZPOyIQpswbUBP/rDFVrxuUEuvjOB3Lw2WOO261bqG4k2o83T0wp1prtfbHXc0fNIVATSkEo9BZ7RR@a7XM/glqS2bwuROhqJ/p1ejQiLXsJ1mhKvrprSi1S16v@BlaqGNry4CfJ0eiWKtReNVKpJeWs2/EzWxNOGxNo8v/R4UYN4U7VmrW7v0i21sY7EeM6OF@z7py8azdpyHH409@@nsDPfh3gasVMGTDzU7FXtqnHVrF1d1Wrwr9Hzyn@D61Xtxp9e86u6Bii8rk6x0VtNudGSW36DnoJdkhvoIsktMDTg3QbAZjMSvUR8Yc1TUmJVF5tKIX8qMuoTmxX067qMVZRNNSvnp58W9tRIVBUEeRO93uLIBPxFORJFLr3MmfUyObx8//W/xrv1/ut/A1bIGn4pjHwfWvjrvMbfozf4e@3h76SLv6ev8XfyBn9PPfwdufh73MFfJFpnDFik2FbGzJxnlDPlDAwGywCHOswMlR4OCRmdZWaZGcuMbKUHJh1@GTAZmT7LDFjGyliKAp5g8FjGQ1MfXgP49SEWB35GJoORZ84ZpGLiQEMaYOn9ts2SrUiTCS914G0kJS5l4lIhHjdO84XxayEdb7ea8dNqVHZbLZlzfUzNVUn179UVa7f3njxot2XsB63H9uH8f3g4WrTe@h8d2o8P7ZEN/8PDw8fQ6qn7KfE@XPVGqua/tqKN6larIiIySz5aR@XaVquRFdFcSAGKquiW@shrHiO8GxutCIjEz59fVJ8/x//FefWiSobQCoZ2NQTwwbgBHLkDRPC8WiUDmuE6p1jJhsaL563QxA3y8wtwes6ASQ//8pLt7@Bv/O/1f/yMJZqnSegHl1e1BF1J/CWTl1eXV/6zkUwkfEuiBj90ADsGubxqoJGALsHUTCRPk1dX3A2eiWSNR9jANGoNCjwHBIoR5akmWnHgX0CuTPjrYa3WNJNJVjvgEs6Ma29paSVZpU0nsQ4uh4EspSQJIp@rVpVNblZzarWa8y3FUrVa8s2xRKJ882pktpRCoaLmcslktZrxYUFsqgZGiEJ3tW4VO141Ok5ibnl3TGRwco408ceFinDvXsL/dsPWeAxitFLOvH0bOrXbPcNpt9E9@/at0BZwg0q9nAd7pvT2LZCEeBIE7Ce2vzRaBnFZkdV5CkPN1TzPSbwxxmkBN766QpJ05WYyttOK//IH3/lOK17HDQrkmlMwAoyT5Wu1Qq7RKOTAXChBOYUY3/GSGKTKSvIqJgu8dCAOx6O@l1IqJsn1Ko7@LFpjWw3oMC5e7PIqSs3FcvlkojPTk5fgErgp5TJ3ZLlCopQq@7/6RpI1Npn/azab2VRus7h5//T09Br3jUSteqnVlav6pVbBuZqratdXxo4HHrR797JlqLNSptqKtNsPtk@22/gdN1yEhnGIoSORxwguMI6deJMm1vLl0yaW6LQVj1eq96l5lVKeReNVH06MA6VlpTIVPArSu9HHU1BTijUS5U@6N6NjphSzMLxFxrQVqJhhPVxNdZjd72@AI7QX6@DCt6ubZqC7/sJ2zN6F0dM3ItGjR9u7eydptQYjpbq/vZtWj5/tRBW05ud28s6i/ene9oPDZxDg6NHe9vHeZwdf7D07Anc38uqNpuuaPtH1i/ZkcvEa1ZvrbX0MrvOrrXcNV3v1ShvTxaqcLF5cvP/J997/5B@@/@kP3v/0e@9/@qNffv2j78H9h3D/gL9/8G/LeXz@8ut/8gfvf/@n4Pif4P6PcP/8l1//7rf5TfY/hfvPF9z@1L8X4PjNKtHGJl6ABiW1lNqEcWezXAZUINdaBNL6zV9@/cOf/fLr3/ox3P/Mv3988/7tn6@@f/Td9TeG@@Ef3A7zg38H9x/xuALYH/w@d8P3Dfjf53C/9eP3v/Pv@f8v/B8af/r@d/4UH77lH//4L/78/Xf@g6qW/uJfvv/eD95/94fvv/ud99/9/vvv/gP1/e/@SyWz@PiD9z/64//6J3/0X//k/6L/H9Lzj@7yf//jf/xX/@9f/f9/9Sf@/XO4/z2Yfv5X/wHQ@G/@@Cf4/@Ef/81//An@/9U//5s//r//5jf/BRl@jxv@@z/7t/z519/53l9/95/@9Xe@XvP83q3Pr@/g/vX/Ape75/Mu8dylXB/r8vWvlZ//mdqYpwI4QHrmmQqs5c5MZ1UWybCM/4BO@KN/9P53fwNw@3cAEmz/J9jgzy3g9X2yfPnlkl@K5hvE1JdfgqD2pS@wfbkI9H3G3srABmfuvwWAL8mXXyyEgkT/H4QCMOZDBWBLiRMIbmPkzr/8@p/@DN3DkOj6G4vxZQLXBdgYAr8Nivh97MxhMRZhv4/k4P1Pvv3@Z//g/U9@7/1PfhPHAjFXTm@nReUDs5kAmL8DHAIW7gIHgAoKayBVb0RUMGzUcPYtoqRevoRG2AATSDmbkXwWbBGlQWYFzRAQZPBNimSawgkLuKeRXBlsOEmWgiE4xb1S4LWTwg8KpyLTOvgRKH6JmKGxUcKZMxTn6xAvBuJh0u0SSA5sukOxQMh66ilrb9anPGAKHRoUA8MModNTQVGFVKn@ABKsTx8wjAsjT0VewvtlvVGqTxsY3TvKAsSR2oEkAQo/dJyaNt6BvU5xAnxk@uAdZKVUT6UaJXCpU1EptXSb0lTyVDgqe4pRudGdMdxKuHWfsU8FpSTw@QaoSuZD4zM1h96i6bgt8G@lNv3i0D8w0r2J4aGdplQ/3I37b6EzhfcBIF5RxB1ocIsi5uY@eE95VClKFl4pHgPUXMqf0wwdiEFJRVLUvimyQPqQh4@5anxwxuiwOLFYDEy1hpAV2ocgsDHnrOJ6moOLZMQtVphQKAvojDt6@DbF2BHJdZsPNuGpwH9vg7bmUkmqm5FYHCcL4ixISUxl7Zwd5YUISki2TSpAigDZp@CD9/37YIYaovfcLRKdh@MCBa2HMqWQY8lIgj6ck6QZCR2ZIBZ57A527Cnw8mlBSCsFXOdI8vmKyLfsSqX@TskVI/Am@wQ/2eN/PAYaCz9cLNVqWOmNS5GmTtAIjGEh0mj4C7pMiTSO904A/OSQKWpGYsD5X@aKai6fy6vZQiFfVJVcoZwr5EtZIGWFTF5VlXIuVy6Vi1dUlvtADdKVzU6@1vh7N67/4@@tula74hVpfMmmEs0LX0UaZp3vJ4zhwq7QyghVmsKhmos1M2n8qdksPCGPaSVfPN3YMC9FLHKLNrFd4tI5ZDNyKU5xHvoTuFjkkwj7BNzggkRwbYv5uxEODqv@yjN@do@vPgtKHpAnGWkB8vDooBUvLy8X7kh046uvPNZoAFsvHuxHooD0w/BD96LRk4YSfSyvN3F08h0w9uDgi4Pjg8Mn0oODY2C2v8XUbEaKRK@urvrhAgFZdXZ4eBhBagOCU1bB8FddNplMyLcD9qupFlFVUc2KWUVUsvj/gEHF/93hVfir@IRQWTXCIuPFqwp3BBH5HhDpewo35gtzYwaNNf9odCNCK5FNQKLTCH5bqXkaqcmh5wmeVH8CjQHoa7FHuBfXs9mJzfd87ujdNRC7Q/6V8F3HBsno14fZ0awz7vXA4EdjQ6@HGurQdEeGN1wD8Ww8wvNcuvO/LIa9UQcyiGsSHGAHHo5p26sAiuzZ0ZpSPg61XeCiP6m7APCnB589PFl4n@xt7z6MFNjO4ZMH1155HyjPHu3tn4TWIvcNgubDKL619@jRdav/AppYJVF4g@WL6TQMLfDAd5ouekuxFwGIIt3ycZuY3ChVHf3ePaWuvBNrXow9q@@8Sz2ZjErZslLOAwJAqQc6SO220YOyRzVPO3JiLjt6hDI8SuL1hmZeXrFcEeT59hfAKYDs3pyw02pjb0vJRxuRx7gJsazwwzSGG3kIAvYIP1SEHyXzInictocfI8bJkg5@FXgyZmsd4YVOaHSMwRBGgws7AIh0NI3B/bEXhF@UraHebnXweBrkdsPHXAGOK99Gn2UiEs37quVSvlTOqqV0qVzK5ZVCPp9W1LRSLBXLQJkzSkkplPJlJV3KlbM5GDrAN18uRqJAUY2@LMOwqAgCvCsQrdVF3fo1/EiBLQ0bkSifomJv8HP3US20T5igQxgBv/LkerTFetOoC2oOzz9kFQYxaqzLovv7u5n9fUHYQQvOb@9mBKGHlnwpkynuCIJOPrswvKmCYPMw4AVgHrdkMju7gjDhEaBmDkEYomWvgPy6IBho2d3e38d0XqFFxfAAdsZ9uMUMLEUAs9CSzRLDLwivw@gAbpsnlKOc7qEF00Sffe6zC36C8FmQn0wGYnjK4XgMD4Oybm8LwgG3bG@jz@dU8DzP6jfQsk2XIDhgASQUhAEYBo6uW4LQASOioiB0wdSdaeCG3zFATQ2WpwnCjFcQVpEgTAla654JwJj67pjMw4cPtaHX0wf8mjn83YWsgY8xneztdz77rDMYdJzZ9t5nT9Hn888faq9mE6cz6PjBOm24bAgDPmej2fUL8njQbmvmSp9vgI91zac9a@uYt7b2GvLkXwNMZNT@HHw@B5/piovHBtcIQDt47YzgvaN1yCe4yIfe005HqCKierOxjvN12Gfoa@XpkdZ17Crap/WNeCKenjULmdMqObNRInmZqV6hbz9BX8pD0pi8nDWn9cwpCCtF1T@jkRBaUzVvCOmN0RbQuMqGtqWoudS0gmpY7X6cxUVlK6Hc23yTeJLcUrO5itDa2hKFpnK6pSqlSqH4YnMiCMkKPreyxcqbRCaeYQwfyWbxdKuYXwhRLKY0Wa0Ui8nqFdSEB@NTZ@Lp7XYicaFrZ8kk5hW5KMg//yj7jIpoVPuJaXpa55lis2R1WleAVnsTGJcyN@LqoWKKCX6Oisc4gOimW5kKUuiEoJRLAqQvy0mkRUg94P3yebCSEr4WDEtGfkmsIvIv2SmlQlLCDf9tu9@mr/mwl4uQyDxHnuPBHDqUG2yiIzHDrUROkNdG8q8xVInTwY9n0pluEPW4ehXGZzKUYjkSafjc5hH/jkjVt6IaC2kfv5JsOxJ@3dNb8uFKFgIndjwDLmEkHRxKzyxX64exnOhTT3qo4y65buC2y0/OSntT/Dy8YVvVS/G5eEVHz/GsLWr1gNFQqzfApPVYglJnWvKCytVuNOrt@kgfjb0ZyDRUF40wMIytbIdxSDy2E5xcaNd3oLiZqoW6r3S0xqbRaaTRQ20dO/Wdy0mlArBXVb1O338WonjUacuqT6g8R7qDp2wODmN9puNxlu7wZWsPAXehai@vxIbDrGqYiwOX1094cIIydIkZ8j3a9cxVdVBvovtbfNREQTgVxebb00gDulR1FtXq7qTDv4aW6YAwVKhOwU0p5qpD1ql3XkyrTn0MLDyrmlBZC6IJ06oE/9aE0bEttevTebGz9aaaVXGTVFrNlNOqAkMiDJUADXcR7Dm4FbjBX0EBJmEmBMaEdGaakZS0oitpz96zoJYzlQpWNjQTWeGtJVPqppno2UyridRo0EOrlEUtPWRjIz1MQKinumZy8KSYEF9vFVK0oPQacufEEj1pJ7mVq/YSO6ydBAcY2OFWWSFX7dcTL5LVxEay7uqvq4tNnkhGGtjJqcTjDahcXypzJ6Nmhm0UlPSl2BavTM31YkpRrTQnsaaoQPEybwc14auGcAp1f8VAlmCLiyfANFTBLejSnM2YMwpztzHyjKYOTaWU1aoPEhn75CUhJPBzuHwTZiIeL6rxeDJeRfl/A9x98kS0JA6ELX5P2RKAUREqQlkFYW@BLN3IAl9dK4AcdhXpGe6Y5cqR6GXk6vKqtriv5BtsNtNSYmC9x9ggFYswmVaVpXaUbZBJlBo0SbNd3x483a760Nu7kWiFNlHNd7ywln9gVZQ3PnYpO1VrvODvFu7hgFQjpI@lyU79tXs1C2XuLdihfO5lhNcq39og11INuRURBOqpfB2ulE/ynLJ3UVKGznYvgw@9Vx6jKM0SWoX3wOZp8t0Tw7wsZcUGiYAJFn2XghrB/WAN@V0UCPoVVbS/6@rycnx5CSLuFR7CVrP5SNSygw1ZIFh6QOlgJMjnBZwS0dn4uPyi@KL04vGzw2eH@@x@plKqlBbFg9b9dFqJK/Eauw8MqPF0D0SPt8zOK@@sz2krWrQarYzj2Vw8uxSsHp3Wc8G6akJpNESlprItwFVWAXrTVwpi5m2DI16DPAoq@Lz/jR/nprUS2FVg8ipQp/mU2mgom2oyOn7/9b/Bw02Xe19sP2JxLODf/tnP1OLf/tk/p9W9@FWVF7oYBUg0KoVi9DTKs5ArsiRY@IqyEm3IvrtSVJJRV@Q2yF4@6r711Uwk1EwJ/HYPuU0oQK1Fy9FItPT45VvGaiADNnqDgaGSSZaX5KpYBWQp@LN3OI30Ttx4CbTEdWMyrjmWETiY@thsNBqbtDcw3kjheTw1T1PuzavqKZ8sQAli06Kf7m7iT38ROmy6LtgDG1g3azrLNxQGIocsv/@N31XVwt/@2W@3km/bb9vfBJJaLpcLihr91c0r6iuJUSEvusU3iFbwZKtY4jvdkTq/cvl3qoNTfvSNYuBtdUfD05GoE940rDMIgOM5mPHrl8AAVNgdjxRG/BH4DZ5x8c0dzdULucDmzvB79jRrh0f83IosDwxvOOnQmb4TZ3bgHdKJBxnwxQCBncwd0@7IIw0nCuiTRy6IPwCBGrInlgyjHh5YoE9CIseJehvapIcHitZrA1gbi5VIViIMUh7j2ePWtN8X6NCybvaO9bHmoAoV8A9Odh70EAy18dCR6OA07hI/FB7FpRrXWXyXb0sX6Uy1TbyHGw@O4lHVMtL3oONBCQFPBfsHfGjHuSChDb/yKwS7zQGib6MKzwCef8U9DBB@F3geAsuIKkl8PqC@WCKWovKngkzgvC53oHzMrX6icwdKiHLjMCOtOQPSNmWhrh5IKwHNKqFqwqZSOU1zPrGuUH3T4W@D1eoMWG9UcUIlwQolJY19wwHWSyktKD8hxotCLpYjVfdzAoC8QfCwM6pZwv37ducVqRby9TAg/kmBn3/@HXU5oRHnVSxfQSm76BgeAcDQRgAYUh7gyRheReklVO1MBnjkAPuCZDsD2XDdiZ4vlnKUIQ2PMAegwI8ugaqyrzlZpszhieGwFGVvyEz9XDfpTL6fbVRRp/FOSXiGm1dQ@x4y2IUkoQ5U5VJJoRYS5TR3e7C3/2j7ZO9BmolKHsHx3FfXDmETC5XLvVPk3zcn7tBHIwzCu6/UKeQ4kifcdPy@HE/6Wb@/WO2pxQwHEeBHjnBWb5yI1ymYo4/wi1I8YjbWekir0hTGivvH2vE8OT87ZbiYlYljIt4ElRv0/GhUQJTGtKKIgktfNYcwWDCftwEbEJ4bQGtpBdSAT93aIHiMUWkHYa6w6vw3EFZRbHCtBMKuiZ@Yi6MOqEVqG6e@o7H4Caq2hiGdSNtGnOgC6j0Y1uOfuvFqF3jzgKdg54lJ8tIvgWH1MRcJXnEn9s4saL/ExD@VIkCFJIEnTobHVH7x53HgM8L4XDPhJS/PNYe9qQOGUo@TOFHfM@n0XyLOtZxCsDcS8hz@abC6Vw0DdOzeTEIVbVZvd2iYvcSbxTTGwGoa/UQq1a3Xs8lLSNIZA3Fyx0AMdZTXklV06y@5hV9ll1stC/InbVr6Bfvy8aOH0ORPdTrs3XxxuhmT08DaJqtYBK2eQKAHh4@PNMfVnaQ0xvd@KAQl8KMQfiIStPbIbWZOKfdpAYsmYy8EyjnQPb/07s7sRBs80UZ6Iq7F@TErTMqARjFqmsSFoKqRSiWhiFrTOF2qo7qw3LhC8nJQJ6iho/erHajos@qVWz9PDJJVD17DxSTykERdVSl2DwLVXXhcq3UDPxH98OTxo3q8pjGMtb6iV8RTnRA5AFEIYej8@LbjaLMl1AGqQljl8ZOShDBwpeJCY7ksNVlrxIFlXZufRzapdpAkKT5H4F5ikvYxzqnfbNKqM8eC2VivowMf2j7bOxHSENaZ6El0tHB4mxHR4koA6kEaHN2QUtAQODtGmHo9d@8euXHdH/W6mskkATWrVxCbC5ibCMUep3rlaPVeIqxIbWysUDigSqqsWe4FanYGljeTL27ZDgwR9R7wkPdcICF11F58bnizey5gWz1QXnCPn8Ksb@Q2S4fGzje/LB8XHiS6nc8VIS28cm0LRDRnvJgBR7uQOFsENNbpcuyiTKAOx64mj7UzW871Mt1SpqQUe3oxr5cy2VI3r2fLHeASu/1cqdMrF7VivtuRYXDzKIg0MvAjRAJHf0y2f7dk1zFmJZDx@30FuPVevtwvq5lsNtcp5XuZXK5fUrRsttBTS51y53aubZ4fFLcCuotjx3UK/Ol65i5yg7b7oZP/Aw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&  xxxxx  \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v+] >>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._V=>+=""[u ];>E?15#>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Bosh and yash share the same code. They are separated like this:

```bash
echo $((9999999999999999999>0 ? 166 : 244))
```

Quoting [yash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/152252#152252): "yash treats numbers that are too large for a 64-bit [signed] int as floating point numbers." Bosh just wraps to -2<sup>63</sup>.
`9999999999999999999` is a nicely looking number over 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

[Test code in all shells.](https://tio.run/##ZZDRasMgFIbv8xQ/JRdxEDTFpGlDO9jlbvYA6xhqszW0aFgylpS9e6ZpukAVwfPpx39UKZrjMCjRYofanPugVEeDWGORMkDa0w2ARTGW9wYHLlfBGRdfyIHTLJw8YWWFw9zj4PdIsgz9bPS@seRLmLkJNXVLLVNZabd6Noc0/3mj7Zja@fL0TLs8e894fK70dxd/KkWnhGEQ2zCqvyrdfmC/7xgjgbQ7t@BQ4Bc/CrEigRJNiVC@Jm@oNJCQUUp5UVh4uJK9tUM@4Sp3lE8URtHaHzv2aH9jY19AiLPZZKfM0Q3GoLIR6g8)

Comment: For anyone else curious like I was, the final [VIP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score for this ended up being 0.00078131539.

Answer (score 6):

## 301. HTML+CSS (HTMLayout), 14246 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa














































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body,text{display:none}:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0  ){:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:peseps>Ex Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:F 4, ._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8ogr ca34* 16  prstd   
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4@cLzI1KgbpEUCZAAH@JDZJVKJd2rvlWlakl163ZTLBZIgiRKJMACSIkslSq6e3Z73WPvrKen7Wi3Pb7dPePZ9noixjuxs27v2DMR9tcJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOyQQIUiRV1bYjNjYWJIBEPk6ePHny5Ml30/B6P/95BC/2xOlPu31nxEamN2Jt17owXZXdn7J7huXl9Iwkoa9dtzsemPbIK0kRpjHmjQx3xPqG3R0bXZNFwFZns@@O1R@ZbpJ5psmaZt@5BPcMY7Z5yQ7tltUGSGzknJu29dp0wS3L2AOz/2bwZsRazmBg2G2PDV3LHpFrjrEnBnx0xq1zZjS9kWu0RpZjg1Oesad23xg02wYj70PX5IG2GYBqnVOYeZcCY48c1zMhBqdlep6DlkWwNFzLebj7@JMF/1qafWIAUsO@OVmIXtPYM8t024shdPb56cHBom2GfaY4Nju4iZKWZbvjkXM4WoSfY7td0zaYrhZVfdExD8Qcmf1CupCecwK3A8uF3DRErpVmOWOPB03TBeKLLLy0Rj0VApw6nODMsftTZk4AGODYAW/miFmYWyyXTqNP@J@YLcduz8CDlQlwAK45GI6mTGG2I3gAnByXeUOjZSpts28NrJHZZn0LsHM6AhuPQYazc3N66biQ8QpnRULEG5otq2NhEJECT0Jme2A2x13mjEfDMaDnsbblGc0@eGtOWdvsGOP@KMma4AbEI/vLnmkLlCy7i@l4NrNBCDYUAY79pga0sfp9BuicIzoYtcd20OES7dFr0yQszTaC2p@RCyAZfc9P/XzEc9FguCeu03WNATBq2yQafH74hHktx4UvuNEvLwXrwLSMEdvZYdH9xw@irBqQUXWbUkDSCrtijEV8R3Zh9MemxwbGFOK2R1C4mEP554eQwDuLbkRLLJrJMD3NslmWhcJWYHouzaBIFMEApVbPaHDnmV5gWQ34PhdNYjwd1@hafZND6Tr9DgLaRo7Vc0yHZzobTXLXFsWxzTIFlt9m2zm2Dc8iK@oQCULMMq2YgzsPN0AoAgYa3JksjylgC2QnSALbYx1jYPWnHPpwiOBbLKexbYAIaGoAWS8AhKKOEOavMLxRDwjbMy4ApNK3zlFcmIHEwNxKwSu1tZUikYWykUfp9cx@H2MFQgGJcgW2DbHmIdFZiBnoqBd0P/HdHiWf8NpOww04bkOKC0DeNFAqjaTahhu@QQzpIG90EC46yAtdA3sdzBmECv7y4JaHvMoHpNXbRFuQrhBWQ2KiQNGQBhCMQdZlsgwyLwvZm8HszWUY4AkIbOcZyJSCxgpZVthmQK5imgHpNUAG814DWaYBEhoCgyzVIE81QEQDZtEAqJbJMSlEVy2D7hA2A2GBBFoWwmTBDPmi5fGGcJDxGkSpQZy6XpyxFuCm5yCRuQzxnJ6HzNsGNyCWDrjqwC06YKsXwB3DFoBwBWTJbZ8QRn/YM5AWkAPIyMBqQJAc4ESwwT@Y9e0MZyny3TRHVku6lqBU8RowLHF86YESAKQJMxhWoMCAM@6JBRIwDgJpXliNPbMPXAQypGWAGdkWSjtKDh@ONVJRzkI1ZToXWJFS8Z@LxiMR0XSxFgV51TZdl6FfqGy9JAkTb9z0zFdjrGtneHVAOpkgWDuG1Q8QoKJjjKgegHfUg/im82h3XGdA5WuAwqLvOMMVYhdE0yUC@tS5NGeozySXMRz2QZ6DvQmEGBt9QObSIH2A1IVwrBwhCIThWj0LAFJUIFct12wR7UXSIXQGJPA8iiWmV@9kEMr9ULWQYUMHhKqHYexxv1@C6s5ssUw11TYvUmjDq475KgNx8CsTqA8FiKYBdTlVpohFAOmOrlI1dernrOcM5pPGxcthkPSehVVA/9KYQu51QLKYE2MAGgfDat2GinsAHMNzEHPC4xXPIWs7dnQUQLl0oXqFRAcpAZB9osnIGpigjzkQBHM8S0ijcCPMmlNgZaJWViV1jGOyQChVWiQUt8iGLHhhgYqtPW4h1TBuyyYOggrBo9qqCnC50qmiAYqcaxpt7g21C8QopB9BbWcC0YUq0CJAqKGYtgfajqcyC9VCYPiu0wEeoyoaVA0IOounRWnHlAdWE7WlSkRp5JvBeZ9ZrDUcMrAH/QTQOkgXoI51XlrsNTj2ex7rt8auO2WTIWSANQBfo5bT6QDTvjaHPQDBBm3WmragVEIqkWmktkMSqDVcSHLwtWmCH9uEZO89@RrrmkBtqJE7gClx@iwBwyElgUhh2Ly2tg2gFCahNZwSWQBMEKLjOCratx3TIx4BbSYo8RiZZ3apREDx6sxk0AC1D2BO0AhsYFkQOKJUIXyMUFqaGIxKZP4npg0lpgXMCGUdsg/10V3WAd0/VFmjcme0WuZwJNjDISlm2SGF5ugAFRqyVQQw1etJm/dAF5vDQAKvks85oRrcOCfhioo@6VkGiljRwIA63TYDFZZxgdKf3ogefFwsxC6/QD9zGLyQV@AwpJKA2h3JhvEIJQgKRavVQxE4QiFDWgYUMnd8M/lgF47eHTClE8SN2GggbSQ1FVghHqthKHD3bwJSh32EVZ2zQK9zFreANrzBEshOgGS/HbZVU4YKsvA2oAPHdpZABWIGcNHLvAvlBTHjCUoNox8wIxUXby6PUE7P2r5Yf0HVORw6LpQMLnSmKMl4loW4y@HtlFhQRcSh3Txfo0JNEcV6fjTiba5hH9pBVMSwpII@aYCkACHGWwAg8xweYwhhKvUES@B3SRKfMxNUobZtokpquFMOBJIHtTJENGWW64IYvMC6gVc9fh2iEp9CVWC02yhZkRxU7hcjV5Gj98ZNa7LYzGihpfrSky4Ml3WwheGCrgGFKBbteNF4mewpZMhJTjnDUYqC8qcMHsmTClke60CjBSqCAxA0J1O7FZPnipicZPJ41CnIcTBgQK6asa8Yw9Eidi/BDplmcA7lmr7KrAu1tqLAU0E7wgQdUio6GC6oF1AIQcsuFttNg70B6eEyZbJHoVEtpLemZoO4TLsdxCUIgbiE06vyKDy3RQYlVKthCtA7pZwqiTkCviclKKAMFqmUqD/RgpQ87kbqDLcc29Q9wGJcA4mzq0BFhwogRshYoHNYLWvUEFrKnTu@vrJRqQCzgRIFYrMdDyv3fj@KCpIaPKukhIhI1JFzMsKyEYtDetHzNccGtCXg1EqVXY16LpQ4@r6WwBOQVbKRk33Cinx@bJ2P24sZbaMlepKx1IGuZLVGclmCyp@Xhso6qkbnqArKfxSpisyL4Qn0DeYlW8xQWXhzTQ@13opAJZTDMcRA8OpSEvGgwm7G0HvTVl@oBNwEhZ1Loyagfy5a6oEgSgqdwC@0N0oqB4LFgcNhT3ZPP62IssgdU03LLs1Z9J2W0SfrTfQu@2EfHt4/3j3@WmMJjL7VLC1apKxsIY9V7XiidO1xKqvqpc0wjBngB431sDHgvB9ZEs5McSYhVWnagspl4pPz6PizRZKAJoTkoBjAjPeCSsP9gNIlNQ2vt1AJs24iAVEGQXy/TDlkPszAgKiju@Hj82T8@jVm3iJSQ2GPmPXHBgfgW6YObT@cio4LCpjv1OzwGpHCghZq2dj/OTOFffr4fIJa8yIypEqHWOaTo4P94wqB7RneudnvK@Ql5Y1AlzLctgo83x@3TWmZHxB/YGqxhDpDHPVpwnUpgVutOQLP8patgA8AsImjOkzpD/ykeT3AfW8xbWSrtAIOoG@CsKhXhvWh1ociGsIDq7gWtnSX1aLkMKusAqulNVbgOl9ttXI5cztbDFdbrVmc7TDQASnFluPrjS44nXsK2qgzLVKo1QL9k4c3EPdIiYSmgOJj5vWZSnF5fQlbL4rFol5qD1poTt9Un5HEk5kcT6Wifsen2vKozRnyvz@xRrF0nL@1OPiF2Hd3D/UHvmfRUUcdGNRowCY41kxuBwcaWh7wiO30na7DtiAM1w79CEFtWpnM3a5j38ghAy0xqREcuQD5i/01xhDqGus1NRwpVLi5ykc9DNu7BCmt5TNIJKIQgUqRf/WlcWEAuWbpPjn8@j5UIlounQ7MabqABKEwRC40tUK2ZMEUiEgV@CxNYDCKcaO0@w5KaBgBEy0EXRBwd@a81JIkpppa6n8pSl9xblD8pTNdYC2w4awFhhDJDh8/eXj4eP/R7hdnIz2Xm/vOpot5IBzE1wRdSO1xumFp3eJFE5OF4CJQNlwsXiAFxtBA8bvDx54LgltFLypHYAXX8PGf2Fecnh314ouJuURX5aXd4iz0CAsf9yoCQkO73cfGiMuHzbA@R/7pjUZDr5RKQSnvjZsqNFpTL1tO3@imKBxUDP1@SsOmy@ER9mt4y0IAMt7U5CF4nxaoDlPqODT6AwcaLzQUh6KBxTh46qzqW90etIVxvM5042rAwZSaVBtaCNBWTgVpIwFMX0Bb8fbzSeas/ZGmFzhfa2k9m5J9b3PFH/xudExoOsWgtgJSxBc@2dmdsztsClIaIS0CiTB1SwzZYF3QZ6BIUmcptvN94pC0wG5SlBVEo1dj7MQFKZXKpbPbWj6XgmYZNNNAZ1Wwq00ZGKNWTxk5CsBTnA71G4S4sOO1DLujbgmDjyzofR9DUjO152dndh0U9LM7hBsOhNWm9ZpWj5fZzSBbwn@8DNw7lzzkXd8CeJeMwJr0Xla2@LBtqPxhYxX5xXKiHvVxoz6AnYveECKnvtkWSjcP@9VGUKsEHIPSDYiCwo1dmlHsdjY83rkHgcRgnR8e2jgBBOrEDjpw7WCQEohHoahZCyUO8gN7GXuz3jlsLEMOQYSEEzbaoea1qbO9C@UTAvOE7PKE8JjIZj5J59CctxFa02QFpWmNeN@4M3ZxEMxqh9MG3jM69wPQKHEheUijZU2zxXsneWBKBTSeDGhaQwMamuCglVARMikJBh9pwzaUhx28wI5pBQccAL7C7u1B6W@ZvJ9FGWDjgynDfRYduald5espQ3kNXLBGJ8HE74YHfinTT30CUA9eMPJLvQui55BqdWdAnp5RPwU63vfVRGk4HfUgxUqLyUbFGZr2YluJt6Ri8TKNT0ajICgtO3YV3djYiJai1WgSTHfBtIOmu2hKgOkumRQyoT8VTRQiSSZ0rVEItKtHr2s@5Em8jjwwwRr3tTWMGbVSKVNPGjVNvHV8xyErgPLgW8EXwInGKxU0xuNy9RKHOEDvDaV9D3nnpOVaQ0GCr0BFyr8FDTJEBGgWoxbsmmVs062nyKDiQmPLRNUs5kbPaumz@tnVWTtxdh1NYuh42ahAuwoK/Sg2ULuuMx6CwlPLlhSQCfFaplQvNyvRdHQrFisofYjIiMc/LsQTBqd1LGoCT8XOzqJAUkGdWqvnErxJUo/HA0IBHtBab4PeF4uqVwWIvxmvxxNRCBuPJkGcVaJRoEsLieBRorElzZnowJoAKaFgQtUQ7osnRYnGcrC4ft0c9qZu2EPQWwXaKfY8zwaxoTCQ9AvX7K95@LAiNNdC9vVF7g@UQuz0Qj1jOOVSUeKYnqXmJlT49dWF0hk4IyP1uQqNDTVUzUQ3oilFgRqEXDgkSvYjy8MibNimM/bCPXRLOw4xdrA97Y1BWPqzTZLAVdZQMls9h0U37wF0FgyPoEqAIz0KHy/yAbRbKtwoRLE2x0EGqJVpGoYFchGnaPDeDI2Q4KLH79PO5Yev1CC2MoVhaYzI6tqOaypAEggh0aQJmmIjVZmYiXFIPUY3@vOF6x5ESQ1WywSJeNB3DKItF9ehcZThIBQe2rUQ5NhsS32QHx0QjyrPC9dsp7YkGtR03B7UEJAalMR6kFsD4ZByvGFbHU0gqBQDrW/OkbeKQFm7ZG1d1/OtXKfkuyFXALF7kEnYmrOhaeg7KRo4xkUm7/PuFL9t@/jowT7vc0iB1ke9Ftj/1Bg47THoY6K9cWza3STbB36ybGdgARn88K/P@8eOM@KtY/hY1aPBG5vWYNw3qK9ksTtjbbiW03T61IWyLujM/9j1jL7BO298193PH4GO/PT0pKKWQp5SxsVgbdzYf7c8Wk7Pw/BYHQ1P@sMqHmdMeTMnY73lT@JCMSMc8ugwFlO4II98@22094sUjj0I@wLaD3D6FuiYovVNn4Gl8FgkjzilC2fCCMsrLX2N9ivbLoE/jfxxhWuG7ZWmk/3FqNOZs86Q9bmCoqk/s86SNZ/aNde2CqOU455wntecnzCgPPkJpnst@hPCKxia75l9f@TtGBQTHF2Cur2P6hPo9KjB8jlXJiigQxxEIAmNQ1Os1TNc70ZzH8rUUOG@pcgGlROow1KouUibKSa6hstUUqC5zYf0PC49HWgSU6/DTpUP9GKTw@WtnRTvtN5sAIidatmfhbPKG8YUjQbeCCrhBiEomTTcfSOpweQFj/qiJQpSlrwUaNsTPa2cTbb36ymPiNBh8tnZ5OO0/gUo7ThXavNOqmuWMbqV1KJv3n/b6oHYYInJPMkgH8Z2x@m3FT5YBPnPeDMDM0IM0QeztUjgg43l@hO1LJz8ISbUgbgMzfG6AXch66o3PYRmhQWAoDRcsTfnyYs3rAY12IXqDfvWqM6u1ZHT6GHiR2PXXpw/xlVK1zWmniRmeFTY7vEnn9fSdQ5BGhg4AFTguTXxpx@CHgx6D87yBBPOUxlZI6rYaUDewvRqKiA1obECQB9g8AjKLIhIpAhRf2O@maWlY0KDLWYi5t50kGRm/Frt9I3RyLQ5b/FRuNXk5sMlIpoKRX9X9L2XWJoGKEDRtNANUCyzk9MH@8fHKnCoF4vu40BGCYqd0eqBvrEq0T4lw4kvsY/bUfYxholj61WCIgWNiYYID8xbBuaG5gTEjqKga7oxsIzjGEQLrGnYhwJyhUsQCGcbtUZEowBYDFrTdzmw0lL8n9q85STwLLEoSxAlgdyxOyWgrRVXx7b1SvWg3iA1FLxEeduTppZWNmMkvja1OPGPaw1wDBWaTKQFQhpqNbYB0o18y6zylj2vpZViPbHJ6vUyHxmHgKjT01RVMe3REPTkw0gkIAXOh6JV1lmY/OrHQD2eGIrjpwHPSoJvAVl33JzeLKXypi7HA2SV12DBHeVFJJdMzuQo@lOCSITQDKL5mUDz84xCyXpKjeyFSdWQHB@BID04fBfjqWQbFabF4z5mHNAzw8Wmc4k9cTzPavZp1menb/EZVEFlXRKEEZB8yoSjK2PBILpheYZyhpkxm@rLJ9AKSpA7VTTQksKUkUUszq6QmERKHanI3rxBC5lt6ozYQMaZtpy@136bFuTjQweQfShmDod1DhIaYloHio4zSfYbb/PjpujCGwapiwWdV7mQw@G4zmnZ5w6NvgSmRlrVcqhnBqEH5/2bITuW16PHnNcAB@5XX4WdN2h26LHEAw1CiOFtsqDubaFhQ3YaqWN6UU/3kpjnp3TMRds0O2O7S2OBaGbKq1t8KsUCee40m9Yqr0AEnKXlv5d4A1mJJU9Xs6rmlx7s4IFqEeQnbxPNkr44G4jN0R0qqRGEEu//@o020P9m7vSgvsJ@wMDQAE0Bc0rprMwsERQ/6LE8Y3l39bhvGUQYMt0GsmW4kCSjHxiWg6YhcUUBfWOAHfwix4E38QG66Bo245jz8Tn/vTySZUNcNsjt1iq/C7OjeFQ0GAPNxTYRgetclkmBSMjyTDAnfEAk1HBHgXs7Uv4UJkbMzPO9Nx6N@RPU4Vsz0Rriva5sCp/pnNHUTGiQGk3LXJPlrnE@bjvK8LwbqMX5JX5nqacRWQW0EjE420Dj8uTzBLpWF6p7/73K26x@TV3S6zau8OyxN1Sa1LZv8y8qCIM1Mbh9/lzlxRIrfALDaqpZfXq8JycK6MAoYm5CCmd@KiGiWQtk7hvNKapCvQ/nsmCcHyROpZVIpDMrBnqHw9XhsX1K4YvF5aEnaovTY1nPQ4rPLlV43xwlWMw3vSVXobqyBkZf0dsh40phvmyawA2vwQgjhTEvcHzlYmnOzaiPFVJr3DfcmWkNi8/w8AcnVvVzi2pDlOWW07c8LND9VVLTn6s2iwvn99IjNB/BWkbJNjREsR5XAtNyKeC0RjiHcwVbvYdM43MncYZqiE9UZxWxWs4l3is1iB40hvlzeaX2eilW7yGflH6rb0BVvrJGmOt1xF7NW3j10vJMeiwn7PlSREet/lL7@VLg9yeG@wdv42zP6jseO6HnOgJ1XaACfy7n6TAtLcNWqJc9bF4jhvxJB7MMNfpdp58vdFMGPFbm@tjtoOgX7/cVcoGQ0rRbhJSvATm2Jt4rRft5yj2/LYNo3ZSLE05DxjW17DJJJQZ1VqcO2gY4Irg8ZQfpAoVUU7wPcUXEOJZzaUz99y9Qe6wirV97DKekUYOChwGKBTCMXK5l/yKxZdfH1n4/oXQD7PZtiQhl7nnfhPqKnjeylOlp7QNDaOn0@4uoTn9sjs2lbY2j5ksTl9@uaWe8P1JpkYxNMQSAow64ViTw9Vo0Dt8La6yq8WutMDGg1W7ers3MC7UhKOBDbD0/AcMTNNwM0bXHw7lcnWug2cfrSdYb@kXaac9hhy4fKocKtyhLcyq6Z9K9ttHEG3k4Y6uSTafTQocJDeXMfaxrTGWCsC8t/pyLmGxmMc/84vCdGzIuj4PIEp4TuFIE6ava9uS5WEzZlm2Opvh8T2nadJz@h@QUCNW2hdoYKJc093Vdjt1Qd8SqDjbrvfCwz6PZWdVvwWsb0bwE@mC7eV2mh8ea3is3FRxNHeBI1/zn@h6c0MjVbbHgMmjsFuKzYfurdUnRIaKpBXV7banjGqrTNPsGf03y2XXwimpmLbx5oSFGgXHUmI8Vz8b4IwtCaTgFYlltaKj0zIFJn2sUfaP9cuz5r5WeJg7eq5wnptlKTfbN1ioPQwvkgo3PucHpkLI0cmxoYo1w4h02Vfo4tVPYrpLA/nDiUiIfDoyuyfd2WCcpZ30WOE2Ht@xmxuW9FyU@NacFwWY9zKtZAgrVuTn1/PdSgI@mLcjX8eD2HreFwt/CbtD3KO2r5pTerGLtntOze2aPT@QOvlYVDuDHEd@LYx3qgHW312IkmsJzzsP07Dv9/vvQE0UjF5SO01mK0z6uRsWlVB8Ed2o0wUG8bu2/M0ZcdqBhZanpmWOolzxn5AxNhb5Wee1jXw9/rpKh/uj3L9qJtLapDxTx378o/Fvbll3DGQ2H9GoM@2OPHhRUoUXEt@lNHT7nBcnOHLervnYGTVVYqmJCDA26LxcxTWvU6uHibc7ZZtdptnrWbUg3TWNkW@cpv9eHf75X2xUpYzHlAVqrfQvI605V5JdK2P0EX4erMl10IPFqLTCs0VeWddLROmllaJy3PN4hiiZWwj7hUGnkq6lLtAy99GpsjWZAQ5Okgh5ePjKBhlW4i2kZKzUrWrQwE8NiusZKLiUlHRVyxUyDwqOt7F@am0AXKmKZDH@sQiicSsIoNOHlQ8gtJhVRB6EV6roF@zn@mpsNtbSSs3vjrndTYPIe@zaoaPhYKgJ3u7gFEy6LdZjXdy5pqhrtPDBbWxvqz4bazLDFa1UG6P0UrkeEdwO0sbG5dsAlt3bEhfxpfcVwLHg14AWZOl7Zu9a3hh5/MqWzcpxOTJ@CVvriYCKn2nR5M1tkWdvs8PERNN2mPA4cGsEF7URp4Wg/dq@jmOcqGRdpttMFca/02cyz73eVQrN0ZtJyxghqU@WLx2bXwOndD60Rzg9dwi/EzMtmNN0K@6tjw7O@OoaUrWJD3FyBj1G64VX4@LUE3iOja7U@ncuIAElBYDG5lL/mCgZa3cyLy57l4eyqwLCmywpZjjMxcl0DWhRLfC526gf7SsxKPV@xuNT3so53ZzjFhV1TMq3rc7dG1P8q3qsalavmna1F4nI8GI498VqOA83fCvdPD87J3ru0ALjyCoQu6xn90fI@7FBnLOhnorqcGVfp6V@3@k6Xfb2QZqDOgXqGavsSxrkPFfcTnDTk2ks4keJ@zzFR7AJRuOzzXkHemhmmWLY1Wt/PMxrhBCL/jYnhdQouikg9xKd670MhKKfLKfLw9lbAbBXxLTU/cN6JM3ZbJhqDrUHCDQYRq7nnT3gWtYZtXobbb2vHdaCidOzxSHHH9tpaIb@2ViixSSEfYgMW@@r@o6fxMDfQBPHb9FMTmoVjrz@dmVbOJlhgMssGFW21HJ337bcyHvCdjI5pdvItYXZxu6UWiesHzrKW0JOpa47euykFwn88eGC2cEzx1rgfO48c24HaaAiCcnBs8uX5c7NAlgfEYA9xATrQp31rNCcEdkUlxLUNY2g2IX/7M9P71EUc8ANjZKyoiqjXkFqGgelWXrH6TdN9Sd2BIfOqxu48Qp@aE2p1rGYYXgaVUavFlWXsqZsrI3NjOd7QcWz@JGmbhpf2aL1UgaqAHu8/iq7i3P@5HoOlLbf5pB5d8CkkZpvvH7Eqra7ZdPr8uWbCkm3xCQOGa5le6iFuR0B2@SxTQPvy1sqQ7bUyZNZoAk32wvBoBH95I2QGUpt8wPygnuG2HBwjE4Y1U3dCewjcIqaD5QR8VkETCD8BiWW0xmI3w9vQ6g@aA3qsbEqEcvPYbOJCpCZtvDEyJjczk/cZiV0HQtO9grX6vrjCQp1nsSfQTonfXm3NtbDmqWoN6UGSeuVAOs3kUWzLbL02sD/NIXrNeq3n3CHNqcdkXNGLHSpG1L@cMmhR@tKSND@vDRSavqmMeq4Jyu9oXce3vyPKkpGS8cDE4ef58ZmVqqvj9SixzvKR9kC4uqYiduMDWRLszMf1Q2V3peaJ4OF/dP8rKaiEG/msv0sIiK7bx/YB@bFri9f7cOATxxt1rMkR4I0rElaJE0xWDoLAi5cMNG2tSgTknj3u836JbmhS1qBNzTGFdoRVlD6J65GpmPaFQnu2TW6myOHrzFK7uL3oyGwrYssCHINQHvpLzgJv4r1kaDUsG3EmqJbihJ3ks2Ju6DLiXvqSAfQtZ6QMPXqnht6Tw4dHp@rQ05a3@nu4UuOGHje3B4JeSIc6q14abmgklM9Va1veKHX/RFP2Hh6q6GEFvflYhwIvHLObe63sERWbeRopY2UrCF3N0XIF8dPTRw8Ts1WhLLbXc52BGQ87752cJHHVy1dOljqHQx9A6eg4k5XBD/c1Lb6EfZ/aNG64SnouiWkVpFMTWqPAjJ/yLVRuVa5aztBsn06H5udQeaIE994z@vzKRD42LqwulkJWXEkoKqisqOaz8dC0bWhsm27wXpWf59YQpWWLXin@WjlRBTWHTMrNLNce1s0FWNRiWFrMUfiwQFr6JreOLAVKRreHppTh/X0R0zRtFZ1PjA7kK8utzKx5D8tGjvvOxXsMMpui8aIEVsoIuEqxbp1kvq0MQHSn8IEd98ISjM2VE2TWAQis80sL/KVpTw1boVGudepFCULjdLe1Xr5uvsdQVTD35wK3WF46@hfMt2exFhnjt0R86oaC7O3dP7wtwLGg5Xpfnzx@yp4YHu4Xst5jGGPzPTCeaUYvFey3ws3qVg60tl0Apa@F1x0uL88ldmK4bceeTm4fnqNlr1i10/a/ASz8Ik9m35pYy@qqFu/XerJ8AtJtcfMVHs50Tg8O7yMjAL379r/QtHSadgnCt5bmn7fkjF/AWQxNxhS3nkMnvs7meGyHd0z1kmLtPl8exxcseaq/rW0sZiQS8fj8zunh5Vl8YZKBe@fTmiLw@@YN2xBLh8AhWE0lFizh9jugrZi4zE/yQdTY5pVY3lMqade4xEkuyUwsvwq2IuTb6VU2Y7gRGKDKlHMNz45gm/7aIEb7QbM3jLQWEJNaLg1faiq8WLMsFk2xEkT75PDJ/snp7unTk1q6fi3HxdJAjpphQGT@otGPM20ZUiSIAcoE31uTFhf2ITraqxq1Hc9PFoOELaSsMpeyWZrkuxhm88owUilaI5dSrgE/ReaxkSuINrTisP0UE9XFEscSX1rWJ4rKmxy0THFCTpRYelnEQ8PzIFnCfXG3fHJlmQy68ojFdojAg13HaYsYPZPdfvkxHuwePnx6vM98BGescGm1R71KMcd3y0SJoZiQTx2LhtsrLCqCRCGvKpXoQRQIE1WjrEQrE2mnSuBe8OZTB9c0itBbLLZJ8IGC0SBTUv/1G6nrqIozx@LgN@ojFWWC8uiBneJqoz/7SZvv5OzvMeAfCeEOSFOntdySWEm4Yh0hUpSK23D1wRC0czItGQy2bJ4dtiHRRt7AlZeowC1uHROn3Rz4KR9iZx8/ImIQf/dX7GjAXXqglXRh4XpBjkMHN82ZZ2UctaQNllS2i6deAM8D6yMSgPrYHvGNKcQy9gjwkRqIiSTbJGT53uNyyGN0ZwNYuWl2LZt5Nmhv5qjEXgKfYWO@xBetKko1eiOID5ofd6L0RoN@yOONXXa81Nko9e7XvpPqlhmYJ@n78PUr4qsD5l/l5ucpzOubO/HM4g8jgbtOCax55AHNkd6hAz5svjh4RizcMMiXf8waQNZcEKXRO4@BPxWbyTM4sdrnkFHAYpBLYlEwj8906zHc9qqUSiEb4cCIShMhzQmflbCw/VU@l89qKUBSufAB0n61XVxxxQHG4yVgfOnCGlZeNIG9dnaYjMqAWcmXeW6mNo3nGflFgOgm@JUue4hcjUEYCDILAW5VEQwqiYQWx6Aoj6JaFEVR24Hag9yxlsFvWxBCZjEgFqeRiRugTvCkl5E79bdxa@LpKaG9zDcFIEWDKohMcVkS61gfOyNgmbkVvHwdK87K4TUVjmF7/CQj2j0NeVC9WZpmy6/8TdNF@VKx3HNQmfRipRfOW/kZgjhBECV5GcvWnrOz0ZldT3HeZMCmPxQsG2ZmG8z/LNVdwbM83bs39wCLLe7ghcRi905sB7WeA0gMi@kpPZPS8vFZkrLZpUkSKRLRQHJwZ4I3EB2IJhATLdN66Qy93b39w68cPTm5sc8V@YwuegNJXt1JnClqslYPDNFwsuaz5P5B6uTR/QM/I2ZI50MSGHQSkRJtXUpmjRkEOZs2u5i0ZRgupm41xs/42rpFfDP6OtQo0A08tPQHxEtT15QDmoC@GLleWEatXG4dSjN4qRDoPb566AaqsfjVda2@Uz2zI9GbnLCkIDyPqFtYCMB05m1tppDZbyYOExacOHaKZ6V44bKYWV4W5c0MbreC6xdHzvlsoxlhEXIIpdePBkSkpKZ8rytL3xHXpWfbIen8RDS@MUt4O4oQwvn0OoqHQJ36h6uhFJlt5ib2MetBk6JvNSV/GxC@n5m/7VKwlRnfwiMWl8RW2jzimDhubVKaqDQaHYujtCNYSbZuazQfXlyCAo362pMxNG2eOEO@tSqNOjwwfdOxA@L3wZgPX5rsK@MB@OvQ69ikHiCQ3AoEBkpGA1S5/gRSQuyMNkng3nMQXw33RxMJVwftXGwSV3vmpG11QbbH4kmQaB9rWp0Fu6dhomm3NDsqU57NcmFtUfwE14SFyf5BW@hNZggYNUO17LY5iUUvo/FSHeJH@@jls4toXF7GS7SVn9jbrr24p1@A/ra2XpIYI1E6/Q3zlkmLYvGmlAC7RcB8Mxr/XIdiUe15Eh3PU0Fd/GTkPgQjqBGxzsAYstjY5hv2qIw@Y2cxO0k7nChVvueXzRIJaiLBixxURiE7ZOL1d8ywpyyWqgAToK1nt/H12hqymqaqdTBTJHG2ieet7IHGhZtfxCVoq0KQEoGtIAtBwwEw4oVE5QwOYdBdwj1JXNr2aIkzHT9BfagO0oRSzap3WOjYnHnNUS4WSyJD56VikQH33RSHagrA3pBzvi4P1BWL64Fm0KBVpchMkN@UeBGKN8IR@VSsygd0IqF9@vzF@gxgzXbRa/VcvGP7NpQV3F@k9PT0oFGIp2QWrO7vulYbO3L4Fq1Bo01sqg/FNDXnNVrmbbRPMBhu29Tg2wfgrkIHVGDkBZEaCZNh8RDJGW9q2lquFwFFLoDPLFYAYglEwweH@5P5Q2pL3JYL@5//HI@plGObd/OZRv8iEc2ly/DQyjmWYx9vninKZk3PpSv3NuuGMTqTmZHKbj24MHud5mE3dSbLLMOyqdSWnn91PtTyW89r6qtJXa4VKsnz@pNz9uTJF28bb@Py5GIqn8XYdoTtHb2RNUhApLTNigzvpRedH7f0WtNKl6MA9@wMj5@Ut@VUqhatw5@cXsDFPdWqalW9W3/7Nl7bhjRNpmcRPNWNHd2bBxbT9fiJZVkpdjb02m24nR6r83NJI/xKJGIKExZKjduxwaRDdpNds9sd7xtTbm9Fxvg6GImwj77@7NkzNDyji70@FuE5dObHUWoYuQjT0/qf/XTjOnn1pLHzZ98cpMwNfB3h6zvXj9B8ouU@3tj4@P79bDYJVOLmJ19/8rXd3d3sg2TuSS13N6ukN3b@9E82NnR9R09t1D1Pq0dr5@dfyHo6K6t/9uNo48mTr3oeZgteGaaBEZ8FuDXUqc7Za7jOOwz/ZH7dDpkNNDc7r5keeR0Bto5M6deIMF4KK6Qlha8NplXvbv@37x29iowiVT31zIX3KPIqki9EuBEM8JXxvy4i1cgOestfR6apSqUCxu3/9u8hfPUrAAddpjvwqOZ8WPlppKpUKMibSDUPBk3XId7/6xvfuK3f514NLjm7rct363Bt0bUj4Z5KSjqVWvCtFe5odxizR72R6eDL4i8bXswo29DqPq4lEom6qsClNihQStP0M@qwCbMW9bdEAusy4zYsZDfjE2EDbs8ixFPAVMRX3CwsiNW4xbNFf8@WXOVn/9jXsRTJb9wzH1SrIAr1qr5VTdC1cVYqEfVZim0XZMe5hz1a0TM5yl6wh4LYVTld0OVkMnmvgYf@sgnSVJlEZgRknEYsMkfZCJt9sbBVhPnB2MzPh/rbx@vP/7c///6ff49@36f7P@H2U3bb6qS2OPIXVX6xalWuuvLVGX3cY@lSoVRINdj1WWyrVq0fMy39yZtoLhM9wTSSJ3YW93s4I8FVreLDRwO/qhFuU@WmmZ1wqQYf5GMWZLk/JiSTT9QIVMFiLo5Su6hz3Dh@4WuCF6vdg2yS9e2iXK/qOf0Isk6TKeOKrLfpMSciUnQXrg340R@uu9h5LGzwuUGW3IW8Lrk2AlRuv@ZwlSK1Wqpu1kGRZVUfyL2N0kahlC/pkCmrAZdXgY5chIWJuq0WVB3Ex9vaBjvmvF5nCf86S9x6PVXVhjCSwcFbUZxJRIr8I1xViUWu4Kq/3aq9BdYVUddEOU3sKPVqQmAEL7Vxr55Qrq9r6vNEuSz@O9XAWKaLmyAh9WtF2XkOsGo3oXKg9FQbz3cAbGKntlNx9uhWG0hipf68WtuZDyuC37uXQBl7DwBUN@ssmnWieeceiycSm4qyUVuZBgBcjzFoFUAGXu9cV69rO9fXOzvw36HntXiD7fXOjT@9ZtcKPzN3KjZntVT1LHUm2KYO32qqijZq6gwMVXiDP6iGpIgCBUqKbLGtyJBp2xkwMbOkbemZVG7ycX4fVKNaXcEWTEWpaflcXeGS6oXKSgrfs1or5OMqiqKG02ngMjOVvZAiL959@b/gffbuy9/Heh@KZVGKpLaweVDkrQR4PLLZo0eP8H5k2/CH@xG/bLRBi0doZ/OHzX34fgJrbkPlgaRCIS83EtpUZ5EdOb@NYuGXblzRaPSfvNCL21HegsblWC88sPylZdc/@aVVlxR5U8Ry3vIYT5MUoXIPeQHlp4rGK3w0X@Hv4Wv8vRrh77SFv@NX@GOnr/F3PMLfoyb@nnj4O32Fv90m/k4H@Lv/Cn@PRvh72sWfFKmAsr15N91Pt9LauXYOBoulXZbupXtaG1sCaZOlp@kpSw8crQ0mE35pMFnpDkt3WdpO25oGjmAYsfQITR14deHXASgu/Cwcdj3X0i0GsfQBKD@uhd5vQJDFz6QaNCHlFyaoxaqmptW8VcfNumtyXS8WmIoUVhu1F2fROu4CqRezrDk1N85esIgHKnU5kjo7S/HOAaZny7iv9/V1o7H/@EGjkUJRdPbIOZr9j44G4c@1/8GR8@jIGTjwPzo6esTMauJeQrkHV6Wa2BGvu5Fq@e5ZScFy64uKSGrn7lk1o6A5n4DSr6Nd4gOvGUR4VzfOpCgDTeWyTPpQ@fKifFkmQ/AJhkY58CC8cQNYloUeBTZlX6G6hOvikizxgcbLZ2eBiRtSzy7PsF0ADb7gDwpn@PMf4G/9v@v/6CmL1eqg38SurndidMXxF49fXV9di2c1HouJj9gO/NACvjHI1XUVjeTpCky1WLwev77mdvCMxXc4wCrGsVOlwDOPUPgjQZwUL3/E/mHfGLe4znC/6NBI/dnZJJ2Ol5v@/rQ4SmW8oQHTeJlOG9ls1rT6n/6YdiG@GydPuWy5rG0x/qFn9XI5639tF8rlgv@xGYsVb17V9F0tDwpONhuPl8vwcdcHm4bPAGwBwPofOYBqekaLyn05cnV4RPvzgpjIReKYIi4YYmnaxhtPhIjKJfnOnZg4ofHubvzOHb2YfvMmsBkOwUqbs2o02pbbaKB95s0buSHTyHkxB9/pwps3IMuicceNPcaDRCCimKKxj/UqxVl0XCDENjgzLaXPsOgZnjEaubHX1jAp48RXT47TPv/ptOOeRX/23W9@8yxaqciKTLZZDQFgLCy3s5PPVqv5LJjzBaCUvHnFj7zoJopa/HozJXNqMHkzGhFOWmE7zmVjFN2hhmN3q1DAPbzY1XWEsp1lc/EYSNc4KFrXEfxxa61Y5PYsm48VEkXxq2zEWRV0AP7D9mkmkd3a3rpXZ/SbLLtQJJevzIp2XbkyS9jNd11uidPPcMWZeedOpgg0LaTLZ1Kj8WD3dLfRqMiyjNUhPNCShLuEh8cM3WiNMjxXrNcwffWzaLRUvkfMoRVyLBItC39KFGoJVigSGSSrg8tJIe2SJhr/G5JOb3xIoi9oAyzxgHI2u5883N3bP03qO6DS6Ae7e0n95On9iIafudk3OWfw@3h/98HRUwjw5OH@7sn@J4ef7z99AvYeu5xdvgQWz9k7bFryfcmeSS/d14ZpGubYNBuX4/HlK/bSshoWELY/tizL6brMMxumaQ7Bm3@V4W5ZnvHypeEO6WLvfvjtdz/879796LvvfvTtdz/6/s@@/P634f4J3N/l7@/@u2IOnz/78l/87rvf@RFY/ie4/wjun/7sy9/8Br/p@4/h/i8huz8Wd8gfvyWA9Ss/@/J7P/7Zl7/6A7j/lbh/cPP@tZ8uv7//rdU3hvve7673891/D/fvcVi@3@/@DrfD9w3/v8P9/eoP3v3Gf@D/PxU/NP7o3W/8MT7Exz//wZ/@l3ff/I@6XvjTf/vuW997961vvvvWd95965/q737z32rp8ON3333/D/7qD3/vr/7wf6L/T@j5e@/zf/eDf/4X/@tf/O9/8Yfi/inc/wFMP/2L/wgM@7d/8EP8f@8P/vaPfoj///lf/@0f/Prf/sq/IcNvccP//a/@HX/@9a/957/57e/81U@/8Te//tO/@a0/@Kv/41f/z9/8z3/93//@X/@P30TL3/rpX/3Rr/zlN7/9l9/6l3/5zS9XPL@99vnle9h/@Y9g8/54vg@c90nXh9p8@Qvh8/ehxiwW4BPg7n/27jd/GRj8Nxh79@2f4LxJuFf8f6Jr5Ocn/Ov/Awb9ZprRJQ0muH/93be/iyT6H4BE8A/o9Z3gY86Ff3xn9gFk/e2FQBGzNF95FvRCYgtaGFvFoqhAA@cdCvmzL//lj4Mofnke6pwbxPgdlFRzbt9BGffuh9949@N/@u6Hv/Xuh7@CtZmSLSZ3k4q2vu8ZqkAl9x7@0GP@ffyBxy@@gPgnCeoqVRL4xb4Qjl988YU0eZPCibr33oDtF2TFL8adwI0JJ99N2ONM1bAfbkz7xk20fhOOGsmQwGgTpAps@XpKLsMmCb/zEHvieCciepps8f5EfJItOk8kfMz@M@NEYgn0wy889cQ3kkGEE1Fwo5SDaBKTSaj3ktQPwpDb0CgSxZstMkzBZJKYQIsUDBBDApzuJ1ilUklgwArHBz45atUCI1QSiQqkG0PzMMlGAUFM7hMUCFlJHLPGVmXCAyYQXtUnR0JCq2NZ0@VEofIAIqxMHjCEhcAJ7IsXlWqhMqkiuLecHolJ4j7hhMAqiUn1LXxXCGYCO5UevAVUCpVEolrACDGRPHuSDZ5JOUocpT3BEiIP4E09tPcY@1jWCjIf0dhAgnHf@EzMfN@lMba74H6W2BLJob9vpHuLCL5BUYlYGHe/S6riXa49ogeAqyiqqjK4FQWxuQfOEw4qQdHCK8EhJIgjiAMCC2BDzIsE5W@CPiD@SGXrg69EVeKp2dzclCJVOSMf0QhPAlrt7nmJH1vxhjeNSkzOF2W0NmnmN0@dufmEuh22HmzBU4P//gZNyE6wMqG1GcXOvSjj8bGPE/y@d2@LfQypp/fMTmJKIuNksXMdE7qTSMg6xFp1EtJzkG4SsC8BeiOpkwqNKyWkZJIxtRJBN3Z0dCRQI4vnFSkB3K9nNPzGgYDxeByBEKqaVJNJ8VbpTRaqMKjkKt7qJtKcOiOZrmfL0L4pM7Ri4eaIBu1WtHz79i1kFk3KKB1Ci5KJ@Rl6tkCOYMHXL/b7U381gJ4tSrw5zbQ8P5A5RufOxVlcYjG2FZf49F2ORDDcG9ULhSia4pAnamzLn66T1yS/j5C6CIMQvI1XyMV9x70jtnf06NH@49Nhvc4kkw4ENBtD12mZnrdOMMcw3O7jB3x2v17MIxqRWg1jPi3pKJak/VKahObhg@PDkxLjNBE5FAsgxcvU/ytIUdSkyHD4bCcipjTIeEKFI5/gszRLf0wvZjDCalmKtExslgDD4Z@VpUde974zgbZ8UpaTWh6baHHqQWXS15xSqfJWy25L8KbvMcMdk/jySiidOAdc3dkhoknVK4V6vdEIGZyXqlUxN4hpUvVk/xQCnB4xTU@rDFr6V9ltPZvL5vRMPp/b1rVsvpjN5woZqGvy6Zyua8Vstlgobl9L1S/YREVcFTD3K33T7o56mzgjRz5LyyF6bNbSSfzpmQw8AWJSy23XNzb6VwoieEZscYVTq67h80pBCnwEF5M@kthHYAUXxIHzpZiYrHZ4VBYzhnAjgxifNiRrOSjccekMGImDk4bhqxz@gJIE7f7QLUU2vv71EatWob2tHB5IERBYPeZPoFGsttpTiaXaY9ck1y5jbetzC48wUduWN@wbUyimaVWKXF9fdwDS4QGOrtInD9HG53WLbJpgvp4Y0v9//UNeO8MqsOpOaliVdviWP1VcHeEY7QouH6ONRqDgxa/albbToiOOyp1KrU4nVpXbatNpT1VvNAWBKLK0Em32ndZ51He08AxJXCZVSRkptYFiZuQ0GpVKNJWK3tW3c6WNlJtSaYczFutAsb2r57fB8szmtrEO2OTQ5vm8VbHUVn2kHgH7Qji9pOdz1zti3z9ME6JWRUSSI3MyuhJIlmzHNq9LRgeE8lWLz14ryXquIJdr5dn3dl4u16/vDcy2ZbCzNE5mv7oRKJ@Xr30/EK8JpQ575WIDPGMHV8OU0hCUxZeETENIQJZwlHbEJkNVmoZVA8FR34f6oFbf8bcfgppb0nVFzygZTdEy@L/FoOP//f3r8NfxCaEyunSKS/AeQ0aDgLTZQ9wHeeSwU8ehI6/um60VPvZ6Bs0323Mdz/t7@Llv2Ofc6YHF970JnD41cK97b2CNeit8PB0OcPWe6f6jQdgfNAFB5D7u4T483L7jLPOwzZ4@WZHKR8FOc0AMvtUceD8@/OTT09D7dH9371Mpz@4fPX6w8MoJTzn2cP/gNPjc5q5@0FwA4mv7Dx8ufopXBKtS7BLdYLlt36BJOGH1DjQk7ghjLj8zptH4jK@lsrxgAiVfNFeSTv0FVlQ4rKbJWnxBJbZsaLMDoeBo20VJGjLbuWTbadZ2@n0Dj/vrbIBlz8CFIyZW2X06lRKjvnTcfhsKmLkhPcI1KkUNzzRDJKRPAchg3KKVxdZIwq1z2ngQH3bBN/Es8TEedrnCEl5ohUbX6vZGbHTp@B6kpmEwuD/0gvBm@BqttxjxOMjuhkv/pncpIhkjI1IoA8OW2/b4zh3tiQvMXS2kS6Wz9DVwV@W@WW6el4amZw696v4EeI2N2VPgfsNF8djbTGGbl23m5HxL1ksHLJtkaiNibCHdu1alxk5AVakPj1kBe41bRia7BZor1vigreH49F//9k@Qd7dSIKYimizjlNkNTVJJxdOLhVyhmNELyUKxkM1p@VwuqelJ0KC3i6DkpLWCli/kilqykC1msqAzgWuuuC1F@Hyk1BaBhHcJwNotPH5rh7REtVeVInwshr2OGXEWMYLvMZNNCCPjgctQveCavC2rIutZpqUZNBAAosFaLHJwsJc@OJDl@/iBI9B7aVlu40eukE5v35dlk1z2QK/TZdnhYQq4V4E84h/p9P09WR5zALjNnyz38GM/j/0Lsmzhx97uwQHG08EPHcODt3Puwj/6/sc2eLPxI5OhDgpZfhWAA3@7PKIsYbqPHxgnuhxwlz1wk@VPfHzSaYBwzP1xCJ/6ad3dleVD/rG7iy57lPAcR/Uz/NilS5Yh27FcyHIXDF2s6mS5CUYsHbLcAlNraoAdHnaGe8HZI0OWp5xASCJZnpBvo3UuQyNc2GM0n376qdEbtc0uv6Yuf7cANXCxJuP9g@YnnzS73aY73d3/5Bhd9vY@NTrTsdvsNkWwZgMuB8KAy/lgungBjoeNhtFf6vIZuNgLLo1pw0TcGsYrwElcXYxk0NgDlz1wWTaMxaHBNQCvTbzuD@B932iSi3@RC70nzaZcRkbF7RzoxFIoM3R4aHJgtFynjN@TygZj0Vg0Oa3l0/UyObAB6Gbp8jUdVRqjE@KxQRu/mtYmlXS9Mqls63z@Qycmn030nCUnNwZ3tSKoXcZdTc8mJiVcmet0oiyqaHdZTLuz9ZrFHoOClcmW5LO7dxW5ptXv6lqhlN9@vjWW5XgJn3cz2yXwmI6CboOPeG27fhe0uVmQ7e2EkdJL29vx8jWQYwS1ZxMbmo1Y7NI0zuNxRBebJZAEflDqlNJplTuxSXJS4Xixabw8qWhlvk0RS9@A1cY98catkeNyiF0AN7mbLtFRrLJWLMgQfyoVi8dBMpEQgfdsdtOzr56en55@ATILGnyiufSEn@9XFp@ffLqnQgtKfOFeduoBKseOq@6hYJlz4Vut@VanoHSqn0IVCIqqb4erJVynr@5PoBGLGrbv4O9QpIp9ZdTTT@fgoADmMeNi0zJtTmC3TIZb/VltZlSqYDJA9SSsmBG/pMq3Ua1WGpUBP021GoT6jB9HPwNz6HHcgyWwFPwKVxAIh0YlfT3z/3g8YPe5Jzod2g/WqNyH2jxdtnGLWxM/N9kkMpGqbdwF8H7l/tW4hN0k12WzYuKps3IEF6jftStj2zM65hPTxRXfh0ebUMvgugNoFZgsvsnO6IzaPdTCr5Wqy@w5XGKGUm1iz8KcZegTyQdNjK/6hLmi1TA4fHwNbZrY83j5FXy5myzWVu9DMyRbbsfus0YcrNIvOi86TGf5bJmO7ooRLCNJFKTzX@OV6meg43DA56USICM44RyAYkwA12qTgxEfWtflbqWGnt/gY0eR5bqi1N7UpaqiPJOqUHjL04hR8cZN2iuWpZuans6XJ2CnbWfLPdasNJ9Pym5lCM1rVu5D7oseBb7IxygDDYFSAOf1GxZ798vfiO8ouQq3LBOwN33QIxpqozKZZVWmUtOz@aSez2IHRD4Dt5bUMzrO1U/q6WJS16C2hlocwsO9Dd9ZuMEPVOa6ht0UsX5MZkxOpidpVUtqppYEoqdfWO0X8eR5DBQSIlo8OXL28dxbsEBGAualT3gb8YS@1Y@1HWbsKMTKIE3KlE4j2WNDCx4I59g0@tx/XGGZrVh/M4aeNk/Hw/1avVTanwy/Ck4x5dXdfGI7nXgdj5djIELjFc98JVXLUhWFD1FhuAGsLXpfmDce1NIbkO4rpaFcQ3aPNrVtvVQbb9YUDRKYftPdkatynUGOXTOh7KBQ4frOTGOZ2TVQq8YTpJlW1MuSSrMMKDotphdXrRWJSzi/TQCUhkIgInVZ7Ez2F73FotFtPRqNR8vYSbshi741kIL8MGoQx9E72l0ZdCy5JBd19DATprSuKR1Ws64lbCSzbFGKXEnXV9c70OxM0XQzUAfZBpkUtXpPipQYA13vTOyckdpg7ENnsSV2qs/5@wznuQJciTaTqrE6zS0xLWwrsc9xDeddFgXEDHdQ0/VMvaZvQx0IctX3qutaGbugIzihVq0C5b0rwG8nUcXlD5@x6dRIKD5l7zDWTWxKlOjIItl3K7vd492y/7WHXV9nkizL5agcuYpGotfwkyJ8zYXO11ywSGjVBZ@n2TKBPm8jJC/Y3pXfnVLCww5iRolLh1o9/vax1b8qZBTe7geBdX0d2UxRjoip6@XPXug5yCPb8eeyQ/sHuzOgesvlsAsvknox9L6uFzKPDo/sB@6B6U9azTbkaoSlNQVnhpdLwjbHp7LKxYIu6@fJCLsXKUfYuRLVSjTdnQ1Pis@3nxeeP3p69PToQIqcbbzZcLB7l/lkYW/tr3wVPEYz2ShjZ5XIpJIti@lE1aqi7ejsLtQCDE8U72h5Jf2mytm3Sg55HVze/fIPspOdAnzroOGWIAtzCb1a1bZ0Fo8M3335@7gZwdX@57sPWdQzpuzv/uTH@vbf/cm/pkk60euyRx2I2xHwiUYtvx25uhpeXV3Dxd1ykXqEI5XdjoOZ91trkdmM@lLKMLa2E1n9nl1OCb/athaPeEpE9M5v5yLeG@Gkpwvg5Hefk5WcxyyI7B9bOV27t4NMoQULcdhslNb0isAVhUcv3jAGH61qu9u1dDKlUqz0VmE7b5Ud9ha7n98qG@xFpYpDphou3/F7Wbeq1SpCYdFqIrUVZXoO3GrX5XqCUS8tNAafm1v21tk8R59tsGLRBnvT2xId/GdbHrTstmz6mVueB5/@l7n10mMyDkGkUu027dKyY7JcFfJ/KwXonMXf/fJv6nr@7/7k19403jS@gLqhWCzmNT3yc@3nPwcPa9aN@00z6o7GBd5oCJp0bMXpt2oLWpN4JHKHcf9@Aw@bdAzUBqtrQ3sdv6QL1IUoaxp8M6J2jLxt4bLSJGnWtFVIvCxJgQZKmrPbbSUJBtvC/cehbEpX0kfoBFUrq4C4lD6agQKLAdSlTqvh9cfukKapxyicVk@yOxAEYvgId2/aoOWwQuYqIKZSWzeDcpQ9ohppRWxgeh7uBQW1iPQRBHkIbE@HmrGhgSu30adlg5BX0QvhSQ7tGsRdh7j7PECDbGOUeu4hyTh2PJAN2rX0EWgGRAULNAZm7YCHMgiWj4AAkIaYAGzV2Q7LxNmVlUiUZxtNXeOUX9wvy/BXjUoYDKG1cZWyH7iM/sAKtHo8twT5QuQwqGchSx8Ih8GHJCvQLsDg9IUqFy3rfm9QAIu2UIlR0tidOzOsKhWrHWeUIoR/bg2xV4rywV6OKwDz21Qft0tyktmJBGb2R/NsBxRPELrAdQrfu6scCspk/LyWJPi/N9MiRy5kFTmUMQEiv3ipaAHJIDCSnedhi@1UmKZvx1mAfAtwbxFStMFU0FA8m3ys6l/4jteA4c8j/t6/IH1Owz19gm8Xlw0zqPbGuPEqbh7DhYFY7su3h0EpdjjyQwehIClWn3x3LBcaMTQk6u81FctocQw225uL8KBJvHqW4WzaXBxfFAp9M3gbuKuSiGeD@uZbDmSoN3Rs2oaJtozAicrAESCjxG42HO2xfYkbdYu8ocBhjDzayQY5HzGmbaXo7DMKi2OMTRdauj5tkszsqqw1aDO9yGLEaLTrjh2Ai1MgQrhp4gZortPsmwNA6cQ0Ge5E5JVSqS5oReMmbT30yAK@6h1YUJXYXkocM5e6tM6t1CluNKo4HVChxULuCCpSWPz4cKbY5qfvOOesb52bvAM3NrcM3mN6PglKaxIoO7uBsCXsK9YzSZYG5yT3Bfc2vLa5sZAMhd2ITeM33xltI9bAHH1DdZLl4hFyF4Ydoi9dbyTRDPamnr@RBm0HAd9qIHJNsYS@EsXVu8HeEJLYEqRCu1Go2Ik/jEGT099KA42gi5sX4EPRJKxjQGi2/EXpWIohtR9RBUBlD0oW7qo1cku4lQJg4rZjLSh6QsDb7GOW0SU6uof2ORF7kgAMzPrKPHRwg6CYDm/UhoxR@QIokCtQOgdtcMNFvIL9MLzP3WimHc9m7M02BDisdCiuCuPFwv/IhT6wdCA/U9I3wDEPGC7BZCMmJwBsQo7LHHQQfjE453aJZEmJ3YSUZAhBkBqgkKrgnzHJQjtqS@Bw3/D4toti/63Ly0uVNoIbu5ZqerjLtIcHZ6aGXQt0Yic1MgdDcZ6PhSe8Cbgzk8I3l8fjVO9O6CDT4p0pf0tSx6uIyQexaMeLYuV4gZsodwe0gQzu3OIRQx1YtAF7KybmS3D@0@vJK5//Ssh/SiF6jUAYQzCT5DTZSgKwZLN1nuxctsvC4YIKJACHXDR9S9x70fU/Bp5vsoadwIczomUB/nezf95y@g7qJDLvXp1FzVPo@5z6n@J7aE0gkG1esl3XNaYxco@jb2Tg2JTUHjaFap9cwAjVDLviOwFak9q0Phd8EgSHSi0YQXZxdxjpaj1Qvi0kuk@4@wTcJ9x9MovUj7Y2qXOVDK2uMTnI9bipmO8TwUx9P9d8C8WZC0EGxZppHAT6nM7ZXcPdqlBon978C/Kx4jMG8MQQCG7GUrXnZ7Wzuu2Zl1v1RKoLzC4TISDHAXStTjS9bAdmpH7/oj90vDkrG/eSg1pJ4I1WrZ7gBs4rmMYgg4gxOL0s3P6rO1B5PxBXCESCAQLqYeCIqsHuKGbFy8HmouQIjFOTZzTmiNUEMnXSvoSTsAN1iZOeEzYMqB4ChPZBkgBNcGF@yeFnCvjS4ZmLhyr7fhXaBn2A29BE61Gg5EJR4bKmTJkUwkpRfDSB7KiuVhaT4rtDVtQWnELJvBb5H0Z/44PR70C5WI49MSyvMMpSuKjgbCxQIURxIaqyaiWUr4BBasvomy7UXPtcPxW1NUSzlfKbGTweTIJ3iUcoxkKZ34rz/KGFWrItlwJWmFYqkMRphRdLXi58knKCB8E8EWzqM4IIzwUIwEgvDWaKYJNwsEmlwgUHm6wIdhlCckJITngQ7nuyAsm6CAatp@DsXcyeOminOPdLBngar0ZBDRrKDM9RxLHql7hFFo5kijhnMoe4QPAQqtjIZ6360thrIaRDQmsBADLiDQBtfjxRSVoUeJoSfAUyipPSl1H8S7ABlxXAYCSCy3wbyVjAZNQGBoVfTlA9AGVXTtQkWcN5Z/RL81tO@pb@rd20TM/71OYt08mF3z@KZR0pGyqgIe1DS2dRIGNL5qk4cXpO54jgSX49B7S65qXDYkuUbbBP@YdVp5p9p5kaGDg/BA8tCY6wjvvtBxwSYfeGzsgYOdlsiTeaLGK7ZfHzNoPVtR1omoS3jwVdr@2Ynh0dQaa2nK5teWYSD83mKrtJsxX49tRSWE8WRseTJNEHyZuxCJrzFaq6jQYeo9ZoxDyz34mXgmmj@Kkie0ajErZ/wRQKD@JJAD0axpzmS7M1it8OE3c6FsFOrdZ57GgoHKMQyS4DGdYC/R9ce6DBMM@ZtRxpz1VUpZujGG2C3nMGThe0vrGnShh6AfzhDDYiZAyHhEuSGdikLYW2u6ZSEmsljbgI@tkHB2Wf6TEjHoTX5wHMESPJ3EUaI2XdJdE1VkbHg/nxnXw4vidhfE/W40ut8EWcedO8wh0/LOpMbAYBPM7QyNyOBiYd5Fb7BjpzqATWqFfxAO@NYpvmX7UR013wuiu8qx3gj2Tw5cFXgPjnq@i/PgP94Pvvm30Gni15MgV5M8BpgTHant7zBzdj4P0wHpciS6ILWPvBe8YFfvFkkANUIUCNJcFl43aRUDCH0Oz2gk3MfcC38DxOo7rB9zS3qsIdl@DkXiTZub46ix402mbfmJrtmPCZDMH1U3wMDTaSV@@XcBR0JPQc3taLQd0VD1yhGkeic0@lFSxjJC/i8dVsxb1YAfdQTzlheLiafuh@QzRjF1@F91ZDOyAaxa3L7AsLuz@H0@GU70jcp23TfTnK6x@ek7gc/XaCAB3EhizJWbTxdeLzOBYk6T1qhMCvOp9k3DDUh4h7cd7Mww8j0e0phcwNBar4uSzN766/PMetdTke4gqfJ/m40fux5G1M9948F2I1DmwmwvY@rAq5ARlnZLRasTBEbrM2xxz7hkxAO@qns1fUKo0lAjUISZJuZFFzm/SLuIQt40N4Y4fT5/BGgF1z1OAM5acN@7TEcR@MXAbGMKS1CBtQ0gFKiIqc5AKNkC/JN4P3q@sgztbKOFs34mzNxRmUgPkoQ56k1lyUIhcwe9ZlQd/sjFZIZ3TCtjO81oltuGzHcLG34ipqRUtWkkUvoiUQyFEzWtqPgVCOtqOlB2TwoqUTMpxHS5@BYVa2om@iJb9YoAcXPslwD@2FCMfvVrS0F4tfSyPj3PT8eNVoKchT8HOXfxJFgBSYbtAacYjNdkQyR64JFRsplUmGHOMlsflE/TBJutPw5@dl0L776Ih9nFvkmSWYNldphGoMHg9UG/6@zktKcknU5vtHBzSjKfCC0SSgjRcOQ@BBDY9E54URRwxdaUQD3oAgys3ScoxYqCZ7T3RE7MChlMnz8RP1VNIH2jFyr4Hn@iwSOiRFhPfzax4Ez8D3wxMDr8LzBjp@dIQRjsnGl6CFRH0RXZMozOt5XETuh3OI@rrnPeHhrL4XnksENiTTQYejwTmMbOgM55mEXHFmvBUOQ51yvFAi9y4EI6kgSuYKZ7IWKUPBEC788XXJCYVD1OZEEDrW0nVeyoJ6gWQxOs1kXUhT5YUPUAjJHCjhZuucDqB5IIzkj4ubJNUVq6ohPyyPkiTXvJiEwCruqzM2Rjz2oPG6j7vtfFjz1Q85wb6WGAIIhQxi4fLV@QD93eH6u69Q@0RYiGCZYr28Kr2pXq@tZRcw78@ivZmB6JhkD@JLlaMghhnJoXUQ0szX8doNFR@nfHAln0caQF/Q9n2yBW2CW@i22LbgsFBLcC/mLc91sDzXVxPqpkbSv1B9pUXFmAQcnvAA01nS1uPKE74si9GF@reN/gdnsDufweHMQ3iUAHeB5LyUu2ObZrnMyjaIbW6DIlUrMS7Iabg0yOaZJYh7GroNhm3B4qhx/ODo8cOvQaW7vb0dF3X0dIYfllrsaw3qcQ6ZJlAH9cGSZouexDMlcLAbu@PpIOSNM1u@IUu4sAZlwIBYfPYTZTwuZFlIni@UXQjH/YYoKmCdz4qBMSeVUNUxsMq2BF1HQBBzFNsyBBBfvQV6J6m1FqfTExoNPPy20aDqq9HAyUuNhqjFMGv8EfH4zyMbqbHn0uF7/OiPS0miBfHswRF79unuKTv9dJ8dPN37jH3t6Cl7tvv4FBc2P3l6/@HhHoN7//HJPpPmpkfiMUnYoAS6PjBbJp5Rh5uSZRlB3nOGUy53Yntxbn9iDNinTsvEYaodzxjc6/EP1TZHVR5qH5qjU@zDtOgorIE1wvkWdI4TNGNRuWnTyjuc78/AbxPatANs8w6cttWxwK@Ebd@hZXr@AjDWtyAHQd76y0OTXEnCI5to6hAdroYzsC4huAH@cewGwBh8/hWdL2x5PIDZVpkgXHB9MAVP948fnTBcOr939PjB4enh0eMTdnB0DJ9Pvnb4@BOg5@HJ6fHh/afoRB4fHT04PDjc2yULjkBaZbh4/eXYG61FQUXvRJXWOY580zHSwdd8rzdq8OzSoDWIHouObZQ@ltG3XpvtaFkae6i@4LpHGipgsc3d408@hzqfma9whNMfCqb5B/JTj44O20yzHYoNCksVyltZFFeo9hQtTuMRgynDkwTMMq1Tj5E5yXzgNImnbZlM3sM5Ktj3zZezU1n2QUNEGwAbQfkTViqMTgCJRpM7BLIKsbX6Dm5IyGPjkwjFBwa95081KUtEMTFXBoHieoVDG/uDtHJgAXwPFrqIduRyDywTWHAPLMstUBU9xLkjLCd8jEdHYxTPLM8tXg6GBzQszLYDi/sGtWILAieeb5SlBgtOUMLF/X0654X38tD5c4bXsiwK4pF/PAOl3@cFw@Snb4FM5EOJNLcNfMogbDo41CCmvfHDJ9EVuAHnCRmdkcdilbjKTnFykGlb/ISdbt@w@RSo2dQd4j1WwO1bKmKarRWcTEMrQIYOMSCeijWPRxDugdAKzfcNByHv34jREHMk6XQ4fwrabQjcv4HALwIGAClzLZ0W1VS01BTBOB3ByjHPAY7Eftu3Yf/Azu1xy5wLIGZtxV5ar1/HBZGTc@0kf54iYQdZ9Np0Qa2kocyO40IZJ7FKZ3mgFGz1nOHI4nkYm08BjThRNQe@sWKD2F5UqnOxIR0WY7QdOxRpE7h4RaxNYMr3iZU4no@dB@JrdrAjcD5UwnzeHaJjNPEY5dnYWRIHkS5N7H4BRZjGyrHzczoiTLj@Kc1kx1uGZ8MVKtUH98@Uty@SeEAcFwv8TEZ/0iHewJgYFxQPGuejCYsu6l2ipPkH@3jjJoYWc/CEtMRS7gODdmDPgnbdvUY5cOPTjW/a4wKZRXuyfPOmwkMpKJnEMZ1eLzaTbklW86NMUpg6E1NAQrITkAVZH/NtkgQzkNf3cCkM5kIZKGKjHMF2@8KxOUKE@KlrjjsgWcTphSK7A/hxVqUZFbPDXHFlSzg/Us9j9yuJajw1m1DCQuSM@SI66UPW4vHQtBSqr26Ae7AeHMjv9wdXWIsdrx4@CNqDtdA@CDclsRoWr5ZCsN4f7Ns1YHnl9guBhbQnVwPmleRNaAGnB8yZ3IwEs2nXx/jiRt5R2QMwWPdiD0oANBTb2KYhan/73xgPEA@DmSlEJ6cP9o@PmczbJxAW5B42GdpCDCLsDfZkNtvWsknYqYHSFDSWA@XJt5mb0eZf6wrzUuKtEBVCB0kKegTCYnZscceacKknahZSIWj2PQlEn3Lz2F35MsirCcDX0AYEZGeZFkqgtDSZEV75WF54ErigW5LrxuE5/DTDmtfdeCagOw0DCs8JMrq4smR5/j3j@nHJj4crWOarMSW4DZo01DfQTjiBiIfgUVXnc3BNtvhZipPsuYId8WmHE7/S8xr235@hiJG4Es514ZBYF8qxQI3rx5u@mkMTErEaMHCmp3DkM5rBwRfxZLMTztD4rNKLzVdBoGTiKXH3wlwBwevX5eDY8tisnqwECnm4rG0SNjUfyzr2zgrY5dWePsa50PlF8bAYFUjbtVEp/zBR8VpiLiaf5ksT4zsC5Hwul7kN9mIq/ODK3xc2r0MW5edoMIT2/QykN/Woex849/Bx0nefMcAa0vGp9X6BWQgIqs6SOmUu7VQZhfEDXHi/ECCD227jwXuLscbZZAG35dB5jRSGTl5upCFUhIOE8lJzg/rX66NDgXxrfBsfHh8vbOgJpw5e46z8R47rmbNVeaGdVkJWuH513s50XZu88fVMA4QSo2VMaxfb0Wo7PuGVpwodabwtnJKOWJ3Ep90m/b4GioS6F1U8axN798qL3XuKVg4n9eDw4T7bou3wOnN9kbIrx0OyZ8Oy1yFAMpj6JbD6oDV8H3sluAGHpA8SyESr@WJEm/ituBFFQGuu0VEoYlqokK3aYu53vJZh47YfSfljj8nJOxCQemH3jw7iy3rW0@W58ICcN7RjECopK6pMQcEOO3QR0jwInptoH6qwcKWGP1NyzQnpRkorpPNFiVJnJ0f/T3HXt5ZGsu2v7aeogIm0QgMmmkTEDComzDaaLZqMHxoGoUH2IDA0Kkz0fPuci/MC59yfRzivst9hX52n2Gf91qqq7kZMMt9cjBfS3VW1atWqVf/Wv0pf1V6fp5ebxYSixbfRvwquR7etXzqDy5u26qnh3y4mzelvvyq19kI9p7pWn0ko1Px6MctxJF/S/1fqdY45VyP4hsO6niWU8uRWNqWWVHgOLzxRciMZH5o34CExw6Vq@cpwIVzsxsWr2vp5sV/MFa5q/fMCnPzGK8XxSn4lhQ/PaBWlOUY087XxOdbUqNTV798oXNbJl6pp1xDFriH05X1j1B3slw7exqRx2ABABKZtvVmgLvdsLsCaDb4nXt@/TWkxWVqBYx1skJwF9grKw6ed5ckQx7S6hBn1Spp2s8GE/09dZyHnXQ/HA07RFWXAWuque@csGDemHEsUKEute27Q2WQ4YZ4UFEPydSpW1Jm8bNfy8J10IyBqKMnTYeIskYBPIRDVvly1cyfw/EbzEkjgYtk7LqY2N/maWWK1wGMpHkw5GiN2mMid4xEKEPoZsrYBVfDOPWC3D4eaj/c8HuQLy6jG7CfDBvIO7xSRAvNv9YX9m7j8JhFACL8gey5Pizj1zos2kuI7yMIFxCOLH/yhZoBbpXTKAhoL2FJfMQTOluJMI1SryUTfF25BTqEV/ekWZPL89qAZNr8r2ZkkrKfWbwFoyV3KSVv46YXFUpFiGVPMZI6QYuGb1ICki45H730aVlO14/d6hLTQYiEkBx7Zv1fXv2LrD2qo89wiL@mZB@mZWLon6YJUmMujBT7MtBHNlEh@CfPdq0SYLf2grqLizYtHPd30aEsS5i18LW/gjQf1bph5y3alcKVN2IwlZCIpn@f0vqQ8iZWxDG7Ta5Ku@XtV97zFMpb3h3j9@HV0B/lsPKttTWa41Ot3e29k0bIpYLMEUVMpKY7@ZraTQal9MPV0Qjs4yPl52G4VQygreTPj8JhJbG3@kPD0JuNNahYN8WJ8MLDmjJEIlbjOFSbchB0WqR5OfhIBwTDBaMqM3C1TeKoLTyNgkeuJqVa8IB8McGra7BAvwi/yDv/MYI8jZ/Il5ycuCOYTabx4N8cJxJPuk8R8MsVnE7iLyEfdqK@sImHd01mI8yeJg4gU2Nbpiw92G2LwJ3aeiE4UZqZ4QHeboikdZsgb9n2sC5F47/wru@y8bdAee9jzJ6qEY0aDvbCcmIM7Is4GiOzEsWiC6@GwB60jb/hu2YVaBwpZXYO6JYQYWdk9pwLLHsmfxpN2SKdCnjoE5FsYiIQJwXWnA2cyeMAObjG1QuLSHXtOqT8VgQaNmeer4mbuq@tAtKZ02u9EkZCek9EDSgfDRtP3HNqjBbT7caSpbRnfWp4OvxFEGKMlbcNx/nrdbf6y8xb63Jf53PN8hGQ3Wh2c856/CB2siEgmYTVH29i1/AvHieiGm6IbzgBgWu1jof9IvOnf@P2@75RoxeCMAW1aA39047c8xznyrRIYcMHK0EzCD3twPWqKcIc2XQ1iRngJB2lRhxGH4Rfrs6iLm6wrSztQWoXaZurqm24LBDQeJ@0BtMOssECYAKEHCl35YyLKsqviKLHuWePCe5crCKKIGohzEtFNWDL0B@Nuk3qGJVlOj0CJGiSsrN@awYTqa/YacA725iEA95iQAgYBo0r6Gg6OVpr/LhyUbpjRsTdMz2Rp9hvwWKHh7o@6NPuGBOZe4WIR3KmDj99Vqqp6uHf8qXRUVvT84ejwY2W3vKu2T1nHDUU5B7ZV7w73aXax2nTRmh/Sh0SpSiUTnOCUDk5V@acPR@VqVR0eqcr7D/sVgkbgj0oHx5VyNa0qBzv7J7usfScI6uDwWO1X3leOKdvxYZprNcWcsJw63FPvy0c77@i1tF3Zrxyfco17leMDVAatfkl9KB0dV3ZO9ktH6sPJ0YfDalmhYc5upbqzX6q8L@96VD/VqcofywfHqvqutL8/09DDTwflI8VGApFWbpcJy9I2HWFRE7dzt3JU3jlGg8KnHSIeIbifVtUP5Z0KHso/lak5paPTtAZaLf/1hDJRototvS@9pcY5qW9Qhfpl5@SojPhHoET1ZLt6XDk@OS6rt4eHu0zravnoY2WnXC0oZ/@wygQ7qZbTCte1cdUEg6hF6fS8fVKtMN0qB8e0Zpx8gL2DS538iQhDWJao6C4TGGYQaC0R6fDoFFBBB@6AtPr0rkzfj0BTplYJVIBFxc5xNBtVSEQ8jjZTHZTf7lfelg92ykg@BJhPlWrZpQ6rVJGhAoOMU2IdqvSEW41@IrzkkZjVMZyb5u5UlT1V2v1YAeY6N3FAtaK5hcm2807T3EPE3IgQpTuAzKBxFRWstB9@uvERgPKhRGa@jMZGTNo53C3TiqyDVSXChBNadV7NhFKKptFKYxPpNRaypuVfXHfq3X57AB9TW0wEH1dBJ417T1xc/3DmfOV6CS1f4QLJZL3@sVSng261XnfT31Myhsa3Smgx@NdyubqNiIaPkzcEPxsbQvfNGKG2nmlFJxvqQQGBnEL9Z2L61rjyXZXNtnxdDM77AGxER4GoTS6hSqGpkZ0dcUdFWCVLJvi9q9mBC6YMeK9Zh5wUlpGcaRDQv/5d@CKLQ@QDzc4i7spmcYhlNLq/@aYaqYRDIvA/HZGg2@YqvcD3f@mkctHqcOb3OoNBK@W6pgznHdM5sJNyv1H8wu/MFM/MlmdkWe2sw@gH5tzNWxirf9YkU7pfvBG3LIV/9TH/uAYbifkAqSlXxcJqLbRMPZPisEhKKx3aAu4V3MnY870v/VT5hNNcbvVFYeb7O/tdxhbsBRGolha8Gpc7559355KBBhjH4iCSdHWEjGw2UsbYm9jMt5TxEpn4lgFeqy99XteJJLSRvW70onViNR51J1HsaR5@e1R6v32yt0dTJ7B98Wrt5XrBsWG3fkrL7ynq4UivHHVsSOs47dM4KTJKdmjjwyMlEm87ZH9m4GwWGRFk3XQaf0ScB2u3EbdkwkSG5ga4sKUPE72EDzokFAfgeOIYfp07MjUDpGJNddGaq8aEt/gN2isxD2hjlt6Ue22Cf4Bth78Z4rZBmoE0i3F8XeJcOl3wvJfYM6aifLjhwD3I4iUMH0sYN0sDFnWx/Sy8a/lN83akFwMxZcR45W7nkoTEk1kslLGr6MvI/sBxRrQAmKOH0ZefNL/R46kOcMfh7hrBuDSuEhn3bEnIqUNhtG50TUM@3ypSFz17ZmvaVJDyuxopHntanGwDg0RGA6NyDqPCopoBXLBxRGarZAvYH5Zc9UU4FcE7AKegOVa/E@fOa46GUjDxQ/S7iUqhBJYNciJUu7V1OCbLqY1jYcgZI9MfogfD/xNpMgf@Jp04CXpIrUgQwO@iJEMVWtHxlYnSvTWKhoh2I6Rm9NNpCOY@2jGXtmFaezMR/xoige6dqflwymEP26k5BACTQ7ARHb/WJO2yQUenHxKuLg49Sb95NUwpvVaYpeIB3Mz6eZq3XWmjW8GLq1yRNUUq3Kei6gc5uF3wqKcj08xRXj0NEgLONfE/ssssALEDnrn0UqxWZzkrp0eZmQd0qKXIgtOyEZNoW3r/qNZuWUVCZMbmfq35MoQi0FvA52E7@faPgRLz3HjERV6J1TFHwUNIcByTsfjokHUXbIjZ8wHnaYuFIbggZHyLBaIn0DlUXwhNpZ6yoQgqCa0OwziDmG5dj0jLy@qtxZ4lk@BQi/1JX4LV@yLVMjk8CfChMYy6y3vqfWNKKPe@r9nCYtnl6iAN20VUJmIJXR6XoTQHgxFtHRtoN@GY7k5dT33SQge/H1yPdPxCWs@6Iy2RMJt@qgbbJjm98zIjMdwZtaA7hrdCy2P@4CZd@bAQlfAkk8y6ShHzGh7dMkLH7mQlr1KbYcom0YTDkjIRN9W6uruTXEJQHTLUZwp2A3u4YJtNrgd6Bzv8bgejX7D2YwvUb/ktG5k0ApJlgdJJlT7HeGyOpenDQcASDeoKSEAsJfIiSLOGqrRGv9TspO2aEmF0TMQu5Zb8/noskxprKaooZFxdOzHfeoY6E1Ra1aFBbbDQ/OoaozLvwHX/6GGMo4XG1dYqcda3U8qGbCKKT83WEU8yb9qnUzxpIX/xaYDRQ1@g49ZbUCCMPSv0qg/nOcYPNgWfuv6oFZWJ0k6m1RhC/MZHn0GfedGIDnXYv2ZjHPhTOgE0s91JlmHUUz8OLvv1nUGv0ekOug06pyGG@0RmPDxO@REd1hkNbgO@54cTWpFMrWn4LPFlJAwb3q1eshAJzRWM/WEqaqYwHk1LlxImgiXnMAIML15k/h7OxkizZV6shYWcuP8p2@Pl3cKjZZ/n5xUWjT4A6Alua8aCQnxIx@yYFHE@LTzIcPG1DBEcL1RGNdxHLPZiGL8mErEaJoaxQeaBWUK0ETiZPYpxrTVJtzgG4QiBlvxdH9fSBCn@nG7giluaRd7AUmBD5V/lIkVFizJBHEI8TB8n9@rLPxl7QuAPoJ9/Po9b5jECT3FtE20pkPOKjjJKuLB5YJfnaJ6JaRbrdmgV6sWA1iezUOPJ08eowZY/tCnSYfYecCVGZIoOPrg6LlWnKac@dbGoLKkll@N2YAtSGqdyjzOs/y37WR78UOKK5AwT046GnIog/RipmkQl3OY5Y14bRVliKn97xKyufm@vzRCwOM/kLHJrbSphdi7sgdKV9RVqrcGIJuPEDPW0qcdSMB4Ml76Teo/OHXMjs82jddN1v2kILMxWpMVyucWkLU7xOC04s/jMME2cYmxpRjyE4ys/WzafJeKkWMd4K9an36DDYzQL7absomL7uyVjH4viDSx6zUJjhxTjjiClBfu9VqeG1x@fQTRMOV7VecaoY8qoT@UxAmqGTJZK308h5j6N@ww9WkQ51Nsi2kX751GizhrJmZCnJikW5BL0ROB2OG3SvDRsw/gCYeJkh2snKbvhnKSnrMrLZy4QZBgJAhC7Yj8TyqFEght21gwf8e0A7VQd1kJ5zET0tBW1cLBB/y3BOCq/Fu5oi4f6NJM/LwikiYVEpwrO9TVIxt@cXmv1CUN5QAoa4nNIYVv0YG66/P5W/dG2UD6CIKU5WVv65tJojKtWCBv6F02qT7AHDqvSJWMjKj4Q6jw10FigU0qn58txFbu/7kg4HtYNehjRAUI@p/CzoksgnPd6zlIbRSatKbK4mtwy2lyV2ZIiIUPJO8ivh6JsdfngSgB8wZjKF/MEAWFNGXsoBTj0TpTzYojqPqKCxTyGJX3kqKihneecdBBVZ3ixFsmRm5fjdRRGZi4Q2ljMzxMiQnuW@VlCKLTQzcUlkuPl/PaEOWhDbHhfKE5doXslTkPbc0JAemRs7YxSy6t0TnMwJ75Yc2OJlr859XUukpqbTSX6WAxrmfxs6qtcLDVW7epqvGisJNHDjdYaSyRSuFGE7azwx/7YNSUa8tzahEYOGbFdhrbP7uModYtzm/e3QG2yU7bZYxh4Uc9wc/yqyxUrsaDsXw/ArpZYZYDY7X@4tcYy1WCi7wrguHTG2SUlB0LesSaw1KNZOOmaSHs2QIE50w7a6uPx3l4s7OvF1BgaXfmjtVwuBya@iAa/N7bVECV1B9l47mz7utfLDm9/HH28yPLcj1vte8Fgw5ygfeoSGhSBNxh15GYI4EBZkTujHVlx1r9ut6NXMEBDic6jbpOcOhqC4gWoa41ePh6zAIhB6gX2ZzQQ7ftZ2dF325CNpoZi1FBUGibBNwmjPSPy4EMb9tlWU8XAMDEbayZat9zi1hesILjZhDuLwxe7X0Lz5MQ7v9cbpNUn3BSMSAEL97MF9vaiBXKSBRpG9u69DjgebVr5N91exK8YWaK8DnBmYTL3TJi48IiNf@R3ypNhKlH7nKBlhZq8gmauID51WiU6CVcHi/8OsMKHhPZ35b5qDFNNptNsZlrq9QgOnwij5/n03LNPLIvLMjFNs2/nBlHno@txsAZqust7ARPLnruXW/JIdkvcxNkk3wYNcwJD44SYK99XAq5mf960eDNut79vVuRrAKRjf9eMKDeh/LEJkXUAPAL18CN6Ior2XzI0rPdmAorIBgeXdTycd1CgjgKO87RZ/PU2VSqV1OJwZUWVStv0kMmo0nZJ7eLD9rbapfdtvD8rrq6tFWTO3XW/0Mdt8/FebRMMlnCuNC9Hu/RKaUX4jcFaG128mC0upguL9eLmViHI1krbcOunp3/@@3/@8z/@K1vSL/@Dl21@qX22mTzPyy42vyw@uy/gvbZ7vrR4UVscni91CuCyf3HU8EFlnGmE5qPe6MJJyioQ@cp2pOaczdFndFFlbvW7aox@odllQyWbQTapvwZycxTPscmmH/nuw4/ygo7w5tKB2aM8IZEkoFOI46l3mj4M8Gi9IUoSLrADlfKiWzGCe4SDsRmsViWpI/HwnvXGh09LGEkBvri0YmW6/cDvQwJ@w3teaZ7jNOi3O65r/s1@fh90tgcTtXyWUss5tZxWy4kE/@TXX9NXdzHbhXeuZKPjQCKRppRQtQAzQxV0eaPH5we@a2eG3I6zyFf2AJIJU8GZxQsubU9/7CwjF64FHWcBl2YqEZGwkglFkl8W@/fULV8ox30i5mrDG4W6PsVwZRGNiu1fbIEagRgChDVfCUE2BlQlNH3skYynrPmi@9rh24QYMMh69HaPxz0@0Fq02Nc2z7GzFK45YvN5@Yq1sSDO0Iw2UqT@EAFWqMhxMseehEvJJUesvCOt5GaKF3a0fZr5xNZh6o@NbboU@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@ltYwpWPEum3jzJurXPZ/3z5dRZ/@7sN5cx0VOyWWUzKqmV2WbG0mOFVsZsOvZqrNICE2rwrB/PcNZX4sMSIQEhkk3VPmfP77KE0FkS986fJYUgsS4DJtmv15cF@OwDNJNxLLJJZ8Fddk3np97kXUVrK/@iD@WDK7@EhTlUspiezjmjNoFiP91fr8XlJMi@Ws29WM2/oJNQx59kRv411ttMcH3hT2grEeA4S0vP2W8xbogR4n4SNAr0cULtlGtNxPck0E5KegrVw5zrcSxbURlPeILyE5U5XCpcXFybpwHlIw78aUUsZ/JyLCgxHYxwXwrrZzC4Qj2NAPParHeIcCSsDMRGhEWoGUA2l688xqGuGS5L7OfkqR3EbmUg1L3ZZGS16A/6Gb1Zc72lAjbR8Jrpvcq9ys2O0QdDNDZCF/VmaumJym@9efmP/z78NTlObq1mP43od5z8Nbn@KimP9EBvz83bTXIruYls6/fJaZbOwPT48h//S@W3fiQ4SJlu0r@tNQNrfZrcyhS5yF1ya50e8qurVO///f3v1IZFObHhLtbFeloxYgVDkZ1Gn3mX0lUFrZRj6VI4rbBjFmCIhSGdzekFhlGT1Vc5FtMltVXFja8jXxl7FL3Es2HWmE2FRJJh7CloZyQFiqggIyCNCUVbRWw3jNkGmDdEU/381FsP6ATwszbnsFVa042nAUyGFuVYRB2YkhrpPC8PW7k3CWvesZEwNiUFs4XE0U7Pta@eF/4f)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/7tyj5)

[HTMLayout](http://web.archive.org/web/20170702083729/http://terrainformatica.com/htmlayout) is a discontinued HTML renderer for creating GUIs, superseded by [Sciter](https://sciter.com/). HTMLayout doesn't execute `<script>`s, but Sciter does.
I tested the polyglot in the last public release of HTMLayout, [3.3.3.13](http://web.archive.org/web/20170702083729/http://terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/HTMLayoutSDK.zip) (18-08-2013).

When parsing invalid HTML HTMLayout autocreates `<html>`, but not `<body>`, so all the text ends up inside `<html>`. There is an accidental opening tag `<Wr#>` on the second line,
but HTMLayout ignores it for some reason.

HTMLayout code:

```html
<style>text{display:none}</style>
<p>301</p>
```

The HTMLayout-specific `text` selector matches [anonymous boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#anonymous_boxes), which
are automatically created around runs of inline elements when a block contains both inline and block elements. That's what we have in the polyglot:

```html
<html> (autogenerated)
  some text
  <p>301</p>
  some other text
</html>
```

`Some text` and `some other text` will be matched by `text` selector, but `301` won't because it is not wrapped in an anonymous box. HTMLayout has a bug: `text` matches the text
inside `<html>` regardless of the presence of `<p>`. This is true only for `<html>`, other block elements behave as expected. Our code works the same despite the bug.
Some random tags after `<p>` (`<stdio.h>`, etc.) are not a problem because unknown elements have `display:inline` by default.

Styles for other browsers don't affect HTMLayout:

- `body` is not a problem because we have no body
- `:after` is not a problem because HTMLayout recognizes only `::after` syntax for pseudoelements

---

**Golf of non-HTMLayout code**: `html:after` → `:after`. `<head>` and `<body>` have `display:none`, only `html:after` is going to be visible anyway.

Answer (score 6):

## 304. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE6), 14270 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa





































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){d=document;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,2][(":"+[].sort).length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-29]}</script>
<style>
*+body,text{display:none}
a{color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
*{-color:fff}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[ s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1ute_[2]!!\0/ad4ocod"r"n;z c;:0 _
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwNFoAqowoN4EOhms9n3Ure72SLZt68E4qILQAGoJlCFRgEk0CQ7JM2u1hp7Zz0a2SE/xlfWjGfl9USMd2JnLe/YMxH21wnHfPIPaD82Nhwb1j/QnnMyq1AAAZAt2xEbGwsSqKx8nDx58uTJk5knMxum1/3ZzyL4Yc/d3rTTc0dsZHkj1hra59ZQYw@n7IFpe1kjLUkYa3fYGfctZ@QVpQjTGfNG5nDEeqbTGZsdi0XA12Cz97bdG1nDBPMsizWsnnsB4WnGHOuCHThNuwWQ2Mg9sxz7rTWEsAxjj6zeVf9qxJpuv286LY8NhrYzotAsY89NeGmPm2fMbHijodkc2a4DQTnGXjg9s99omYyiD4YWT7TNAFTzjNLMh@QZe@oOPQtycJuW57noWQBPc2i7T3affbwQX0@xj01AatCzJgvZ6zp7aVvD1mIKg3128vjxom@afaq6Dnt8EyU9w3bHI/dgtAg/y3Y7lmMyQytoxmJgDog5snr5VD41FwRhj@0h1KYpaq04qxln3G9YQyC@qMILe9TVIMGJywnOXKc3ZdYEgAGObYhmjZiNtcWyqRTGhP9jq@k6rRl48LIADsC1@oPRlKnMcQUPQJA7ZN7AbFpqy@rZfXtktVjPBuzctsDGY1Dh7MyaXrhDqHiVsyIh4g2spt22MYkogSchsz2yGuMOc8ejwRjQ81jL9sxGD6I1pqxltc1xb5RgDQgD4pH/RddyBEq208FyvJz5IAQHmgDHflMH2ti9HgN0zhAdzNpjOxhwgf4YtWERllYLQe3PyAWQzJ7nl34@47lsMN3zodsZmn1g1JZFNPjs4Dnzmu4Q3uCLcXkrWAemaY7Yzg6L7j97FGWVgIzasCEFJC2zS8ZYxA9k52ZvbHmsb04hb2cEjYu5VH9@Cgmis@hGtMii6TQzUiyTYRlobHlmZFMMmkQBHNBqjbQO3xwz8iyjA99nownMpz00O3bP4lA6bq@NgLaRY40sM@A3lYkmeGiT8thm6TzLbbPtLNuG3wIrGJAJQswwvZCFbw6@AKEAGOjwTWd4TgFbIDtBEdgea5t9uzfl0AcDBN9kWZ1tA0RAUwfIRh4gFAyEMP8Jwxt1gbBd8xxAqj37DMWFFUgMrK0kPJJbW0kSWSgbeZZe1@r1MFcgFJAom2fbkGsOCp2BnIGORt7wC9/pUvEJr@0UfAHHbShxHsibAkqlkFTb8IV3EEMGyBsDhIsB8sLQwd8AdxqhQrwchOWgrnIBaY0W0RakK6TVkZgoUHSkASRjUHXpDIPKy0D1prF6s2kGeAIC2zkGMiWvs3yG5bcZkKuQYkB6HZDButdBlumAhI7AoEp1qFMdENGBWXQAqqezTArRVU9jOKRNQ1oggZ6BNBlwQ73oOfxCOqh4HbLUIU/DKMxYC3AzslDIbJp4zshB5W1DGBDLAFwN4BYDsDXyEI5p80C4PLLktk8IszfomkgLqAFkZGA1IEgWcCLYEB/cxnaasxTFblgjuyldS9CqeA8Ylji@9EAJANKEmQw7UGDAGffEAgmogECaF1Zjz@oBF4EMaZrgRraF1o6Sw4djjzSUs9BNWe45dqTU/Oey8UhENIbYi4K8alnDIcO40Nl6CRIm3rjhWW/G2NfO8GqDdLJAsLZNuxcgQE3HHFE/AM@oB/lN59FuD90@ta8@Coue6w5WiF0QTRcI6BP3wpqhPpNc5mDQA3kO/hYQYmz2AJkLk/QBUhfCuXKEIBGma3ZtAEhZgVy1h1aTaC@KDqnTIIHnUSwyo3IvjVAehrqFNBu4IFQ9TOOMe70idHdWk6UryZZ1nkQf3nXMdxmIg9@ZQH8oQDRM6MupM0UsAkj3DI26qRO/Zj23P180Ll4OgqJ3bewCehfmFGqvDZLFmph90DgYdusOdNx94Bheg1gTHu94DljLdaKjAMrFELpXKHRQEgDZI5qM7L4F@pgLSbDGM4Q0CjfCrDEFViZqZTRSxzgmC4TSpEVCcY9MyIM3FujYWuMmUg3zth3iIOgQPOqtKgCXK50aOqDJDS2zxaOhdoEYhfQj6O0sILpQBZoECDUUy/FA2/E0ZqNaCAzfcdvAY9RFg6oBSWf5NKnsWPLAa6I1NYkojXzTP@sxmzUHAwb@oJ8AWo9Teehj3dc2ewuBva7Hes3xcDhlkwFUgN2HWKOm224D0761Bl0Awfot1pw2oVVCKZFppJZLEqg5WChy8LZpQRzHgmLvPf8661hAbeiR24ApcfqsAIMBFYFIYTq8t3ZMoBQWoTmYElkATJCi7boa@rdcyyMeAW0maPGYmWd1qEVA82rPZFAftQ9gTtAIHGBZEDiiVSF8zFBaWhjMSlT@x5YDLaYJzAhtHaoP9dFd1gbdP9RZo3JnNpvWYCTYwyUpZjshhebwMSo05KsKYJrXlTYfgC42h4EEUSWfc0I9uHlGwhUVfdKzTBSxYoABfbpjBSos4wKlN72RPcQ4X8hdfoVx5jB4Ja/AYUAtAbU7kg3jEUoQFIp2s4sicIRChrQMaGTD8c3ig184@2Gfqe0gb8RGB2kjacnAC/FYDUOFb@8mIG3QQ1iVOQ@MOudxC2jT6y@B7AZI9lphXy1paiALbwPadx13CVQgZgAXo8yHUF0QMx6j1DB7ATNSc/Hm6gjl9Gzsi/0XdJ2DgTuElsGFzhQlGa@yEHe5fJwSC7oIBcbN8z0q9BRR7OdHIz7mGvRgHERNDFsq6JMmSAoQYnwEADLP5TmGEKZWT7AEfhck8TkzQRfqOBaqpOZwyoFA8aBXhoymzB4OQQyeY9/Aux6/D9GIT6ErMFstlKxIDmr3i5lryNF744Y9WRxmNNFTe@1J5@aQtXGEMQRdAxpRLNr2okqJ/CllKEhOuoNRkpLyXxkiUiQNqjzWhkELdASPQdAcT51mTJ5rYnKCyeNROy8r4MCEXDVjXzUHo0XsXoMfMk3/DNo1vZVYB3ptVYVfFf0IEwxIahhgDkG9gEYIWnah0GqY7Aqkx5Cpkz1KjWohPXUtE@RlOa0gL0EIxCVcXo1n4Q2b5FBDvRqWAKNTyamTmCPgHSlBCWXwSCZF/4kepOTxMFJnuOfYoekBFuMaiMIuAxUdOoAYIWODzmE37VFdaCn37vn6yka5DMwGShSIzZYSVu79eRQNJDVE1kgJEZloI/d4hG0jpkB5MfI1xwa0JeDUcoVdjrpDaHH0fi1BJCCr5CAn@4QV9fzMPhu3FivaQU@MJGOrA13Jbo7kkgSdP28N5XVUjc5RFZT/KFIVmRfTE@gbzEu@WKGyiDa0PNR6ywKVUA3HEAPBq0tJxJMKvxlD702bPaEScBc0di6NGoD@mRipB4IoIXQCv9HeaKkcCDYHDoc93z35pCzaIg9MNmynOOfRc5tmj7w3Mbrsp31y8PBo9@jr9SUwenajuOiRtDP5HHa144naccbJjGYUN8MwZoAf1dfDxoTzcWRJBDPVnYRUpWkTOpeJT87Do08XSQKaEJKDcgA3fhdUGh4HlC6pYXrdhU6YdeJxyDJI4sdl6gHzYQYORB3DTR@f5@O3b7HyFpEaCH/ErDc2OQDfM3ng@Ok0DFxQwPygRpv3iJQWtFDbwfnPmSsc08fnY9SaF5EhVTrEMh8fPt4/KhPYrumdWb2eSlGS3gh0KXPY0oDne@OWJS2LA@IPXE0W12aIoz5NuC4lcLM5R@BZ3bIV8AEADnE0l6m9vl80rwu47y2WjXzVZsAB9E4QFvXKsD7U/FBEQ3hgF9fEke6yXpQCZp1V4LW0xwpC57utZjZrbWcK4W6rOcuzFQbaJ6XYdn29cQhBZ56KPtpMixRqtUD/@MkNxD1SImEooPqYeT2mUV5eT8LRi2qzqJfcgxGa27O0lyTxZCYryWTUn/jUmh6NOUPx9yf2KJZS@FNXIC7kvrt7YDzyI4uJOprAoEEDDsGxZxq2caGh6QGPOG7P7bhsC9Jw7dDPENSmlcXc7bjOjRoy0ROLGsGVC5C/OF9jDqCvsd/SwJFShYerfNXDdLwLkNJ6Lo1EIgoRqCTF116b5yaQa1bu44Nv7EMnomdTqcCdog@QIJSGyIWuZsiXPJgKGWkCn6UFDFYxbrR2P0ANLSNgoYWgCxLuzoKXepLE1JJL4y9F6avuDYq/dqcLrAU@nLXAESLZwbPnTw6e7T/d/fx0ZGSzc@@ZVCEHhIP8GqALaV1ON2ytW7xpYrEQXATaxhCbF0iBMQxQ/OnwsTcEwa1hFI0jsIJr@PpP7Ktu14l6ymJhLjBUfe00OQs9xcbHo4qEMNBu9XAwMuTLZtifI/90R6OBV0wmoZV3xw0NBq3J1023Z3aSlA46hl4vqePQ5eAQ5zW8ZSkAGW9q8RR8TgtUhylNHJq9vguDF1qKQ9HAYhw8TVb17E4XxsK4XmcNFS3gYCpNsgUjBBgrJ4OykQCmN6CtePr1JHPW/opu5Dlf6ykjk5T9aHPNH@JutC0YOsWgtwJSKAuv7PTe6T02BSmNkBaBRJi2JZZssC/oMVAkabIUx/k@cUha4DQpygqi0ZsxTuKClEpmU5ltPZdNwrAMhmmgs6o41ab2zVGzq45cFeCpbpvmDUJc2PaaptPWtoTDRxb0vo@gqOnqF6enTg0U9NN7hBsuhFWntapeU0rsZpItEV8pAffOFQ951/cA3iUnsCY92Qp51jJvirOWSa2rxZKj/kD0OeqAPd0FReqtC/K6ZYXbHiZIhgOTW3Nxkxj5XXLJhFAPk0r4g5RKQoOCnhZYL4l4qaD0onoInANyK5SAzWYzeDn48nNIjuCgG/nedqMezdWjXoOTpN4AiEhzzE2U0h7OD46gdww4H6U0VC4KaXZhRXH63PT4JCUkEouOfnoYqwUQaDI@mIh2gsVWYAJKRcNzkBzAVzhb2p3NMuKgHzgNMiSccPIBNAiHFg06IGcgMS/ILi8Iz4l85ot05rgXDkJrWCyvNuwRn@N3x0NczLNb4bJB9LTB4wA0KlxIrtOqX8Nq8llWnphKAYNAk/WtvotTCaBdkSiwqAgmXzHEsaCHE9XQrFIqLpwAfJU92AMp1rT4fJHax0EUsNQ@i46GyV31G0lTfQvcvEa3wsLvhhewqdJPfALQTGSwgk2zJGIGlLQTt0@RXtJ8CwY@9NVdaTAddaHEwGGyWXYHlrM45uMjwphSonXWaBQEvu3ELqMbGxvRYrQSTYDrPrh20HUfXXFw3SeXSi6Mp6GLUiTIhaFVSoF@teh11Yc8UWrIAxPUHN7ag5hZLRbTtYRZ1cXTwKcCVQGUh9gqPgBOVCmX0akocuUCl2pAfw@VfQ9557g5tAeCBF8FhYC/CxqkiQgwvEdtfmiVcGy6niL98hAGjRaqmLFh9LSaOq2dXp624qfX0QSmVkpmGcaHILxGsb7WGbrjAShu1UxRBdmmVNPFWqlRjqaiW7FYXu1BRqaifJRX4iandSxqAU/FTk@jQFJBnWqzOyR4k4ShKAGhAI@2DaOMXi8W1S7zkH9DqSnxKKRVogkQy@VoFOjSRCJ4VGicEeBM9NieACmhYUIXF15TIAFJa1LYXL9hDbrTYThCMOsGWjbOoM8W46ExkBQPS8m3PH1YoZsb6ft6L48Hyi1O3qG@NJhy6S5xTE@Tc4Yhfr97rrb77shMfqbBoEkLdZfRjWhSVaEnpBAOiYr91PawCZuO5Y698Ezj0glQzB18T7pjEJa@1UwCuMoeSFaz67Lo5gOAzoJlHuxKcMVK5etePoBWU4MvClHUSnCxBLQLMiexQS6iqQmfldEJCS56/Ln5bG7wRgtyK1EalsKM7I7jDi0VSAIpJDL@IFMhqcKERckBzXzdWJcQodSl4cDbtkAiPu65JtGWi@vQetCgH0oP43NIcmS1pB7IjzaIR43XxdBqJbckWpx1h13oIaA0KImNoLb6IiDpeoOWNppAUimGHW44kI/uQOm8YC3DMHLNbLvohyFXALG7UEk4KnVgiOsHqToEKqKS9/m0kD9Gf3b4aJ/PnVBni90rzqPV@25rDHqlGDcdWU4nwfaBn2zH7dtABj/927PekeuO@CgfXlbNzPBBs90f90ya81mcllmbruk23B5NBa1LOos/Hnpmz@STUH7o7mdPQdd/cXJc1oqhSEnzvL82b5yHXJ4tp@dBeM2Rlln95SGPM6a8mZWx3/KN0VDMiIAcBoyFKRrUke@/jf5@k8I1FOGfR/8@mqGBrixmEeg18BQRCxQRTdPQokd4Xuqpa/RfOQYL4ukUjyuOM2wvdYP8z0ft9px3mrzPVBRNvZl3hry5idrcGDGMUpZHQnu1uThhQDmKE5itLcYTwiswMehaPX8F8QgUE1wlg769h@oTjE1QE@e2YxYo0gNcDCEJjUtsrAm6pndj2gLa1EDlsaXIBrUT6MOSqLlIm0kmprhL1FIcVyxNelx6ujC0p9mTnQpfsMah05CP2pJ88n2zDiB2KiXfmmhVNMwpGg2iEVTCDVJQMWnZ/kZRAyMMj@bUJUpSkrwkjBomRko9nWzv15IeEaHN5NPTyUcp43MYfKDN1@a9ZMcqYXYrqUXvfB662QWxweKTeZJBPYydtttrqXzRC@qf8eESVoQwNQiszkjgg4899A3ObDRiEYaBIC5Dtmo34C5UXeVmhJB1WwAIWsMluzpLnF@xKvRg55o36NmjGrvWRm69i4UfjYfOoh0cVymHQ3PqScJSpcx2jz7@rJqqcQhS38SFrDyvrYlvRgl6MOg9aK0KLrS3Gdkj6tjJsMDG8uoaIDWhNQ9AH2DwDEosyEiUCFG/sq5mZWlbMPCMWYi5N@0nmKVca@2eORpZDuctvpq4mtx82UdkU6bs74s1hCJL0UILKJo2hgGKJXZ88mj/6EgDDvVi0X1ckClCszObXdA3VhXap2S48EX2USvKPsI0Co7CJWhSMJioi/TAvCVgbhhOQO4oCjrWMAaeCq6lNMGblq8oIVe4BIHQaqo5IhoFwGKWAmUiYMWl@L9w@MhJ4FlkURYnSgK5Y/eKQFtb0caO/UbzoN8gNRSiRPnYk0xky5sxEl@bukL8M7T7uBYMQybSAqEM1SrbAOlGsWVWfse@qKbUQi2@yWq1El/hh4So05PJrTDfNAU9@XIYCUiB84EYlbUXjHj9HGjmFlNx/HTgWUnwLSA7HDemN1upvGnISoCs@hY8eKC8iOQSI1OOom/aRCKELKHmLZrm7aVCxXpBg@wF43Aojo9AUB5chozxUrKNMtMVxceMA3ppDnHoXGTPXc@zGz2yXm33bG4JFnTWRUEYAcmnTDi7EjYMohu2Z2hnWBkzk2VuCCwoQeHU0cBICktGHjGFXSIxiZQGUpFdXaGHzDYNRmwgo8Uwp@@1P6YF@fjEBWSfCAvosM5BQkOYp6DoOJVkf/A2v/6LIXxgkDxf0HnVczmcjuuctnPm0ipS4KqnND2LemaQun/Wu5mybXtd@pmLGuDA4xqrsPP6jTb9LIlAiylimZ48aJpeaNhQnWbyiB40Y78k53nTlLlsG1Z77HRoTRPdTH1zS0y1kKfI7UbDXhUViIDWZv5zSTSQldjyDC2j6X7rwQke6BZBfvIx0azoi1ZNbI7u0EmNIJV4/tdvtoD@N2unC/0VzmcGjjpoClhTantlZYmk@EI/yyuWT7uPe7ZJhCHXbSCb5hCKZPYCx3LQtLSvqqBv9HGhQtQ48Cb@gC66hs045nyd0X8uz2TZUp0Dcru5Ku6ClRfPihaVYLjYIiJwncu2KBEJWV4J1oQv7IQG7ihwb0fKN8VixMy83rvj0Zj/gjp8ayXaA/yua5siZiprNnQLBqRmw7bWVPnQPBu3XHVw1gnU4tySuLPS08qyClqJWGSuo3N58XkBh3YHunv/uSrarH9NXtDjNq7wnLE3UBs0tm/xN2oI/TU5DHv8d1UUW@xUChyrqWb36OeOnCigA6MIG4skWrCqIaLZC2TumY0pqkLdD@eywF4BJE65GY@n0isWrAeD1elxfErpC4XlqSdak9Nj2cxDklvJqnxujgos7GZvqVXoruy@2VONVsi5UpgvM3e4ETVYKaU01jmuE50vrbkZ9bFDao575nDmWsPiMzz8xYlV89yi2xBtuen2bA8bdG@V1PRt7mZ5oZ0y/YTsKuxllGzBQBT7cTVwLZcCbnOEtqgr2OoOMo3bgKKlbYhPNHcVsZruBX5XahBdGAzz3@Wd2tulWN1BPqm9Zs@ErnxljzA364izmrfw6oXtWfSznLBnSxEdNXtL/edbgT@fGJ4fvI2zPbvneuyYftcRqDMEKvDf5TwdpqVtOirNsofda8SQbzwxq1Cz13F7uXwnacLPylofD9so@sXzrkIuEFK6fouQ8jUg19HFc6VoP0sOz26rINr/NUTD2ZBzTS@7TFKJRZ3VpYOxAa4ILi/Z41SeUmpJPoe4ImNcy7kwp/7z5@g9VpHW7z0GU9KoQcHDBIU8OEZDrmX/PLll1ufWuptQugF2@7ZChCr3rGdBf0W/N6qUGSn9A1PoqdTdRVS7N7bG1tKxxmHjtYXbiNeMM@6OVEoUY1MsAeCqA@55CWK9FYPDO2GNXTW@rRUmJozardu1mXmhNgAFfICj5@fgeI6Omyk6zngwV6tzAzTnaD3JugO/SbutOeww5EPlUP4WZWlORfcs@q4dNPFBHlqelTOpVEroMKGlnLmXdYOpdJD2tc1/5zImn1nOs7i4fDcMOZfnQWQJ2zauFEHGqrE9RS4Uko7tWKMp/t5RmjZct/chNQVCtWWjNgbKJdnwrquxG@qO2J3CZrMXHs55NNqr5i14byOGl0AfHDevq/TwWtOdalPF1dQ@rnTNv66fwQmtXN2WC27nxmkhbtXbW61LigkRXctr22tbHddQ3YbVM/ljksusg1fQ0mvhzQsNsQqMq8Z8rXi2xh9ZEEqDKRDLbsFApWv1LXpdo@ibrddjz3@sjDRx8bsqeGJZzeRk32quijCwQS44@Du3OB1SlkauA0OsERoQ4lClhyaqwneVBPaXE5cS@aBvdix@RsU6STmbs0AzHT6ymzmXz14UuWlOE5LNZphXswQ0qjNr6vnPpQCfTptQr@P@7TNuC42/idOgd2jtq2xjb3axTtftOl2ryw3Sg7dVjQP4ccTPFFmHOmDd6aKN3GAwZzsfpmfP7fXuQk8UjVxQum57KU77uKsWt4R9ENyp2YAA8bh1/s4ccdmBjpWtpmuNoV/y3JE7sFR6WxW1h3M9/HeVDPVXv3/eSaS1Q32giP/8eeHfOrbsmO5oMKBHfdAbe/RDSVXaDH2b3tTmNi9kbekOO9pbt9/QhKcmDGJo0X25iGnYo2YXN6FzzrY6bqPZtW9DumGZI8c@S/qzPvz1TmNXpIzN1EforfVsIO9wqiG/lMPhx/g4WFXpYgKJd2uBY42@smySjvZ7qwPzrOnxCVF0sSLOCYdaI98VXqTt9MU3Y3s0AxoykgpmePnKBDpW4S7MMlZqVrT5YiaGhbnGSi4lJR0VctVKgcKjr5xfmjOgCzWxdJr/rEIoXErCKGTw8iHkFkZFNEFoh6ZuwX@Ov@asoZZ2ck533PFuCkw@Y98CFQ1/Vk9bkJF0aNYa@izTEY9VZDZ6Sdw9Cc866Fxja@2ySnbtugrF03uq6drwqMMDqm68cg6tZw88/svU9srVOGEkBWPxxSVDTpvp8sG0qJiW1earIOi6TUXsu7ROCzqI2sQ1fZxER2HOFS8uuBy3A0Jd7bFZZD/uKrVlqf3R8uoP@kz182dWx0Qj7if2CK1Al3AFsewyu6VbYX9tbHr218ZQslXMhkdB8JXIYfjMAHxbAu@p2bGbn8xVRICkILAwIeWPOfZHr5t1cdG1PbShChxrJqaQ5TgTI9fVYdywJObi1H1wCsasAfH9lUtjL5tedwdT3IY2Jde6mXV7RLOs4rlq6LjKumwtEhfj/mDsicdyHMhKKzwL3T8jf@/CBuDqGxCtrGv2RstnqkNTrqCFiU5x5lyljX/D7rkd9o18ioHSBkoYKudLGOchdM/P0TRo6CzhRMr7jiufONGhDnnB3kDdWmmm2o49Wj@bMxqhmZD/xMLwngO3PiSf4K/24EMhqCfLKfLkdl1/tuf5lv4dOO/YHQ@bFjqDg0zCwwKRq7XnmzXjVhEXD2K5CI/S1q7eQHfoOuOROhw7a3uF3Npeocgm@VyIDVjsa/tPXyhhbiAz8Nu0UAsGf2OvN525VtoMLDCZ7YAitlqOzsf2xxKP@LlLR2SDfEuaXTwcqkni@pG7bLzzfDq0RnceMIHwH/cfWU1cObw172fuU9dxoTcagKDsH1n8MIE5W4/lCTHZE9wuD/Rp3ZrNMYFd0QlxbcMcWA2o397MdZe@iAN@ZI7MFV0RzQ3S@C9w3cordq9hDV/TpF/IvWpIO4/QJ9aExharGYa3QXXUbHKVGOfj5trI3IqNN3Bdh/@StE3BQ3@6XqpAV0A/d18r19DCf25eYOn4bL6oh@fcUMRq8dMuVpV1aDXcHv9dY5bk2NwswBzalpd8gocnkF8uw1TQvry1MmR7rQyZDY1Akz03PVqnXz7UmIHUJx9gBdQ1h00XV8KEY42BTujEg1vEdLBpgNsONIDwE5BYZnMszl68Da1ev9Gnn5UDhlBtHlkN3G7UoGNCRubkZmXymSFxRkLIqCs4WcAXV9iocyz2HEYjyu3d1tw4ap6q9oB@SFKvXC4nex3Vsa3mWxNnzVyi12xuei4cypx8Rs4Vc9WhZkSzyEmTttAvbUnz1mug0PQsddQdwpg/OVo3ve2f37JkPWTct3CReX4VZqXq6npdKqy7fD09EK5DSxVnB4IsCc4R5PqhurtS80Tw8H/48KtJ6ITruYx/pgmIrttX8AH58dARj7tw4HPXG7XtySHgjfsOVokTLFYWksCDtwx0ba0qBNSeM@7x2YdOyPSq36LhmErn16pqj8T1yFIt51ylE@YmN0vk8t1kyV08DHVktVRxwAKuNKhP/I1lQTTxXLKAGpaNaO@pJzlhJ7mMsABdRtwLXzKAvuWO1IFHz@TAe37w5PBEG3j60v5pt4v7MW7ocXMnNhj5VGhK6rU5DK13cou0lu2Nkg@PdXXvyYGGEVbQm69oqPDAlbm5x8p5T3H0qJk0V46CMNQaLVcQPzl5@iQ@2/vJYnvdodu3lHDw3vFxAve2fPV4aXA49WNoHW13sjL5wb6uK0vY94VDq4OrpOeSnFZBOrFgNArM@Ak/8OVW5arpDqzWyXRgfQadJ0pw747Z51YW8pl5bnewFbLCSkJRQ2UFLZdRQsbZMNi2hsFzVX2e2QOUlk16JPljpTkKag7p5DC9XHtYt@K/qMWwlLBE@LBEeuomt45sFVpGp4uupOn9fRHTdX0VnY/NNtQry66srPkIy9aHe@75HZaSLTF4UQMvdQRcpdq3mpJvq30Q3Un8wel54QnOxkozmHUAAu/c0gZ/YTlT01FpLWudelGE1GjUtjbKN6w7LEgFFj7neCD00jW@wKqexZrkVG7J@GQYSrK39/DgtgRHgpbrY3387AV7bnp4usn6iGGMrTtgPNOMXqs4b4VH661cTm0NAZSxFl5nsLw9F9mxOWy5znRy@yIcbW7Frp0OKw5g4RtFsnr2xF7WVzX5vNbz5WZGt@XN93G40zk9OHzqjQD0/jv/QtdTKTrTCJ96ir/eUjN@A2cxdJlTPCgvHHRyEIiGJuotGngoS0ejT6wJmqPw2eBlg/ql/RvvFvjenaOxEz5N1kuI8wD4lju@CcrT/CN/YzEnHleU@VPlw1u@@GYnPHOM71OCuFdXbENsR4KAYIeW2ASFRxOBbmTh1kGJQODetJhTLuvZAruPZ7sXQfIplCMeskIHA4ZP9M2CotOU/NyrbPNS7DYqFvVr3HElF2UmdoMFJzzyUwohJzxfDUrJ1DOdbY4gZNPfq8TonG12xUi/AoGuZ1PwpiXDm0dLYhMXILl5@fzg@f7xye7Ji@NqqnYtK2KrIsfNcSA3fxPrR@mWDNQQhIR642eW0mbHHmRHZ4CjXub55WJQsoWileeKNiuUfB/TbF46TjJJe/aS6jXgp8o8NwoFIYxeHLZfYqoxseWyyLe69Yik8iYHLVOeUItFllqW8cD0PCiWCF@8hYBCWTqNoTxjccwktJaO67ZEjp7Fbv/4OT7ePXjy4mif@QjO2OjCbo265UKWn0KKsk21oJ7aNi3/l1lUJIlCXZXL0cdRIExUi7Ii7ZSkE0CB8yGaTx3cYylSb7HYJsEHCkaDSkn@128mr6MaWrIpEDfqIxVlgvIYgZ3g7qc/@3GLn5Dtn3ngX7Ux7FNDpr3lktjZuGJfI1KUmupg9YUbdCI1bWEMjsKeXWIi0QHpwJUXdFzRwlE2Cp0uwW9PEScN@RkRg/in6uKUCJ4aBOO5cxv3L3Ic2niIzzwr4yoqHVylsV28TQR4npl0SjugPnZG/KAMsa0@AnykBSImwTYJWX6muxyKGN3ZAFZuWB3bYZ4DeqY1KrLXwGc47VDkm2hVtRK9kcQHza@RUbujfi8U8capP17ydJR8/yvfTXZKDNyT1EN4@yXx1gb3L3P3F0ms65snA83yDyOBp3kJrHnmAc2R3qGLUxy@WXlGLDzAyJedzO5D1ZwTpTE6z4H/qiByZ3Bi1c@gooDFoJbEJmWenzWsxfA4sWIyiWyESzgaGWZaE24lsXCsWC6by@hJQFI99wHSOcAd3AHGASpKERhfOrcH5VcNYK@dHSaj2mKVcyVem8lN54u0/CpAdBPiShddRK7KIA0kmaWAsIpIBh1MXFcwKcqjqB5FUdRyoeehcOyh8N0RhJBZDIjFaWThwbITvEFnNJz6x@M18FaaUI@yKQCpOvQ75FJkSeyrfeaOgGXmdhTzfbVoJcR7OTx3yuM3RNGpdMiD2s3WNNsO5h9GL9qXhu2eg0qnFjvMcN3KLxHEMYIoystYtvoFOx2dOrUk500GbPpDwbJhZnbA/c@SnRU8y8u9e/NMstjiiWJILPbg2HFRP3sMhWExI2mkk3pOmRUpk1laJFEikQ0UB09KuILsQDSBmGha9mt34O3u7R989fD58Y1ztyhmdDEaSPLKTvxU1RLVWuCIhos1XyUPHyePnz587FfEDOlcSAKDPiNKoq8ryWzYhSBnZryLRVuG4WLpVmP8ku/1W8Q3baxDjRLdwENPfUC@ZEqnPiaD@MXMjfwyamWz61CawUuGQO/x3Uw3UI0pl9fV2k7l1IlEb3LCkobwRUTbwkYArlNvazOJzH6zcFiw4Ca3E7yDxgu3xfTytihvpvH4F9xPOXLPZgffCI9QQKi8fjYgIiUt6Udd2foOuR4@O57J4DfN8YNiwsdjhBDOpdZRPATqxL@0DqXI7HA5ca5aFwY/Pbsh@ceS8PPV/GOggqPV@JEiMUUSR5TzjGPiGrtJcaLRunlMQWlHsBJs3VFtPjxFggaN@trzMQzCnrsDfmQtrY88snzXkQvi99GYL7Ra7KvjPsRr0@PIorkqkNwqJAZKRgNUuf4EUkKc1DaJ41l4kF8Vz2sTBdf6rWxsomhda9KyOyDbY0oCJNpHul5jwWluWGg6vc2JylRns1pY2xQ/xj1qYbJ/0JF@kxkCZtXUbKdlTWLRi6hSrEH@6B@9eHkeVeRlvERHC4qz9lqLZwwG6G/r6yWJORKt0z/Ab5m0KBRuSgnwWwTMD8fx78soFLSuJ9G1R2XUxY9HwyfgBDUi1u6bAxYbO/wAIY3Ra@w05iToxBW1ws8gc1g8TkMkeFCAxihlm1y8/46ZzpTFkmVgAvT1nBY@3toDVtU1rQZuykRhm3iPzR5oXHgYhyLBOBeSFAlsGVkIBg6AEW8kGmdwSIPhEp6RMqRjmJYE07UeNKR3kSZUala5x0LXEc1rjnKhUBQVOi8VCwy476Y41JIA9oac83V5oK7Y7A80gwGtJkVmgvymxItQvhGOyCfilABAJxI6N9A/PIABrNmpfs3uEL@xfQfaCp53Unxx8rieV5IyC04b6AztFk458aNvg0GbuKwAmmlyLmq0xMdoH2MyPEaqzo8zwFOOHlODkRdEaiRMhsXLOWe8qetruV4kFLUAMTPYAYgtGXUfHJ6X5i/@LQlbLux/9jO8/lOObd7Ppeu983g0myrBj17Ksiz7aPNUVTerRjZVfrBZM83RqczMZGbr0bnVbTcOOslTWWZplkkmt4zcm7OBntv6oqq9mdTkar6cOKs9P2PPn3/@rv5OkSfnU/k0xrYjbO/wStahAJHiNisw/C790L18Sz9rRulyFOCenuK1nvK2nExWozX4p6BX8OGRqhWtot2vvXunVLehTJPpaQRvy2OHD@aBxQxDObZtO8lOB16rBV@3y2r8vtcI/8TjMZUJD7XK/Vh/0ia/ya7V6Yz3zSn3tyNjfDweibRPv/Hy5Ut0vKQPe3sk0nPozM@jWDezEWakjD/7ycZ14vJ5fefPvtVPWhv4OMTHd6@fovtYz360sfHRw4eZTAKoxN3Pv/H867u7u5lHiezzavZ@Rk1t7Pzpn2xsGMaOkdyoeZ5ei1bPzj6XjVRG1v7sR9H68@df8zysFvykmQ5O/M3DV0ed6oy9hc9Zm@E/ud@2Qm4T3Y32W2ZE3kaArSNT@qtHGG@FZdKSwp8Nplfub/@37x@@iYwiFSP5cgjPUeRNJJePcCc44C3tv51HKpEdjJa7jkyT5XIZnNv/7d9D@spXAQ6GTHfgp5L1YeWmkYpapiRXkUoOHLphQL7/1ze/ecu0zwNWhY@c2Tbk@zX4bNFnR8IzntRUMrkQXc/f0@8x5oy6I8vFh80fDjyYWXJg1H1UjcfjNU2Fj1anREldN05pwibMWjTfEgm8S4z7sJDfjE@ED4S9jBBPAVMRX3G38CBW4x4vF@O9XPIpvfzH/hxJkdzGA@tRpQKi0KgYW5U4fTZOi0VO/iTbzsuu@wBntKKncpS9Yk8EsStyKm/IiUTiQR0vU2YTpKk6icwIyDiNWGSOshE2e2Nhrwjzk7FZnA@Nt4@fP//f/vwHf/59@vsBff8THofltOx2cosjf17hH1apyJWhfHlKLw9Yqpgv5pN1dn0a26pWakdMT318Fc2mo8dYRorEThV/hjMSfCoV/PHRwLdKhPtUuGvmJ0IqwQvFmCVZHo8JyeQTNQJdsLAaUqvnNY4bxy/8meCHVR9ANcnGdkGuVYyscQhVp8tUcQXW3fSYGxElug@fDfijf/jcx8lj4YO/G@TJQyjqks9GgMrtnzlcpUi1mqxZNVBkWcUH8mCjuJEv5ooGVMpqwKVVoCPnYWmibWt5zQDx8a66wY44r9dY3P@cxm/9vNC0unCSw8WvqrqTiBT5R/hUJBa5hE/t3Vb1HbCuyLoq2ml8R61V4gIjeGj1B7W4en1d1b6Il0rif6cSOEv04S4oSO1aVXe@AFjVm1A5UPrV6l/sANj4TnWn7O7RV6sjidXaF5XqznxakfzBgzjK2AcAoLJZY9GMG825D5gSj2@q6kZ1ZRkAcC3GYFQAFXi9c125ru5cX@/swP8O/V6LJ/he79z4p8fssyLOLJyazWk1WTlNngq2qcG7lqygj5Y8BUcFnhAPuiEpokKDkiJbbCsyYPp2GlzMKupbRjqZnXyU2wfVqFpTcQRTVqt6LltTuaR6pbGiys/Q1vM5RUNRVHfbddz2prFXUuTV@y//F/yevv/y97Hfh2ZZkCLJLRweFPgoAX6eOuzp06f4feo48A/fp/zjoA96PEU/h/84PIYfJ/DmPtgcQCgw2cjn5HpcnxossiPntlEs/MKNTzQa/SevjMJ2lI@gcXvYKw88f2HZ55/8wqqPFLkqYDtveoyXSYpQu4e6gPZTQecl/jTe4N@Tt/j3ZoR/J038O3qDf@zkLf4djfDvaQP/nnv4d/IG/3Yb@HfSx7@Hb/Dv6Qj/XnTwT4qUQdnevJ/qpZop/Uw/A4fNUkOW6qa6egtHAimLpaapKUv1Xb0FLgv@UuCyU22W6rCUk3J0HQLBMWKpEbra8OjAXxugDOHPxgXiMz3VZJBLD4Dya3DoeQWCTDmVqjCElF9ZoBZrupbScnYNDw@vyjWjkGcaUlirV1@dRmt4KqVRyLDG1No4fcUiHqjUpUjy9DTJJweYkSnhOePX1/X6/rNH9XoSRdHpU/dw9n942A@/rv3vH7pPD92@C/@Hh4dPmVWJP4irD@BTrsR3xON@pFK6f1pUsd36oiKS3Ll/Wkmr6M7FofUb6Bf/wM8MIjwrG6dSlIGmclEifah0cV66KJEjeAVHvRREENG4AzxLQo8Cn5KvUF3A5/yCPPEHnRcvTwMXdyRfXpziuAAGfME/KJzh13@Af/v/Xf9PX7BYtQb6TezyeidGHwX/FOXy@vJa/FaUWEy8xHbgDz3gHZNcXlfQSZEuwVWNKTXl@pr7wW9M2eEAK5jHToUSzyJC448EeVK@/Cf2D/vEvMXnFM@vNmcr9aenk1RKKTX883Jxlcq8ogVTpUS3n2w2qnrtT39EpyLfVyhSNlMq6VuMvxgZo1TK@G/b@VIp779sxmKFm59K6r6eAwUnk1GUUgle7vtgU/AagM0DWP8lC1Atz2xSuy9FLg8O6bxgEBPZiIIl4oIhlqJjxfGGiqhclO/di4mbL@/vKvfuGYXU1VXgMxiAlz7nVa@37GG9jv7pqyu5LtPKeSEL76n81RXIsqjiDmPP8GITyCim6uwjo0J5FtwhEGIbgpmeNGZYdE3PHI2Gsbf2ICGjqYsnK3TvQCrlDk@jP/3et751Gi2XZVUm34yOADAXlt3ZyWUqlVwG3Lk8UErevORXcHTiBV253kzKnBpM3oxGRJCe31a4bIxiOPRw7H4FGriHH3Z5HaFqZ5msEgPpqoCidR3BP@6tFwrcn2VysXy8IP7KGwqrgA7A/3B8mo5ntra3HtQY/U2WfVAkly6tsn5dvrSKOM13XWqKW@Vwb5x17166ADTNp0qnUr3@aPdkt14vy7KM3SH8oCcJdwkvsxkMo1Wq8GyhVsXy1U6j0WLpATGHns@ySLQk4qlR6CVYvkBkkOw2bnyFsku6GPxvSAY98UcSc0Eb4IkXv7PZ9/mT3b39k4SxAyqN8Xh3L2Ecv3gY0fE1O3un4DS@H@3vPjp8AQmeP9nfPd7/@OCz/RfPwd9jF7OPL4HF7@wZdi15v2AvpdfDt6ZlmdbYsuoX4/HFG/batus2ELY3tm3b7QyZZ9UtyxpANP9Tgm/T9szXr83hgD7s/Q@/8/6H/9373/ne@9/5zvvf@cFPv/zBd@D7Y/h@jz@/9@8KWfz96Zf/4nff//bvgOd/gu8fwfcnP/3y17/Jv/T@x/D9LyG/PxbfUDz@lQDWL/30y@//6Kdf/vJvwPdfie9v3Pz@yk@Wf3/w7dVfTPf9310f53v/Hr6/x2H5cb/329wPnzfi/zaP98u/8f7X/gP//1Pxh87fef9rf4w/4uWf/8af/pf33/qPhpH/03/7/tvff//tb73/9nfff/ufGu9//d/qqfDP777/wR/81R/@3l/94f9E/z@m39@7y//73/jnf/G//sX//hd/KL4/ge9/ANdP/uI/AsP@7R/8EP@//wd/@0c/xP//@V//7R/86t/@0r8hx29yx//9r/4d//3rX/nPf/Nb3/2rn3zzb371J3/zm3/wV//HL/@fv/6f//q///2//h@/hZ6/@ZO/@qNf@stvfecvv/0v//JbX674/c7a3y/v4P/lP4LP3fG8C5y7lOtDfb78ufD5@1BjlgvwCXD3P3v/678IDP5rjL3/zo/RwhO@K/5/bOgU58f87f8DDuNmmTEkBS74/ur773wPSfQ/AIngP6DXd4OXuRD@8t3ZC5D1txYSRazifOeZN/LxLRhhbBUKogMNgnco5U@//Jc/CrL4xXmoc2GQ43dRUs2FfRdl3PsffvP9j/7p@x/@5vsf/hL2ZmqmkNhNqPr6yWfoAtXsHeJhxNxd4kHEzz@H/CdxmipV4/jGPheBn3/@uTS5SqJJ8YMr8P2cvPiH8SAIYyLIDxP@aKkajsOdKd@5id5X4ayRDHHMNk6qwJavp2TTbBL3Jw9xJo5PImKkyRafT8Rf8sXgiYQ/s/@ZcyKxOMbhH7yFxXeSQ6QTWXCnlIVs4pNJaPaS1A/CkPvQKhLlmykwLMFkEp/AiBQckEMcgh7GWblcjmPCMscHXjlqlTwjVOLxMpQbU/M0iXoeQUweEhRIWY4fsfpWecITxhFexSdHXEKvI1k35Hi@/AgyLE8eMYSFwAnsq1flSr48qSC4d5we8Un8IeGEwMrxSeUdvJcJZhwnlR69A1Ty5Xi8kscMsZC8ehJ1XklZKhyVPc7iog7gSTO0Dxj7SNbzMl/R2ECC8dj4G5/Fvk9rbPch/DS@JYpD/76TvltE8A3KSuTCePh9UhXvc@0RIwBcVdU0jcFXVRGbBxA84aDilC084hxCnDiCOCDwADbEuohT/cbpBfKPlLc@@BOvSLw0m5ubUqQip@VDWuGJw6h9eFbk12hc8aFRkcm5gozeFll@89JZm89p2mHr0Rb86vC/v0EG2XFWIrQ2ozi5F2U8P/ZRnH8fPNhiH0Hp6Tnzk5gaT7sZnFzHgu7E47IBuVbcuPQFSDcJ2JcAXUnapEzrSnEpkWBMK0cwjB0eHgrUyOOLshQH7jfSOr7jQsB4PI5ACk1LaImEeGr0JA9NODQKFU9tE2lOk5HMMDIlGN@UGHqx8HBEh3Erer579w4qi4wyigcwomTCPsPI5CkQPPhOy15v6u8kMDIFiQ@nmZ7jF13H6B48hSkSi7EtReLmuxyJYLk3auTzUXQpUCdabMs318npkj9HSFOEQQo@xstnFT9w75DtHT59uv/sZFCrMcmiCwqt@mDoNi3PWyeYY5hu99kjbt1vFHKIRqRaxZxPigaKJWm/mCKhefDo6OC4yDhNRA3FAkhKieZ/BSkKuhQZDF7uRIRJg4w3ZrjyMf4WZ@WPGYU0ZlgpSZGmhcMSYDj8ZyXpqdd56E5gLJ@Q5YSewyGaQjOoTPq6WyyW3@mZbQme9D5meLYT3wgKrRNtwLWdHSKaVLlUadYbnVDBOalSEbZBTJcqx/snkODkkOlGSmMw0r/MbBuZbCZrpHO57LahZ3KFTC6bT0Nfk0tlDUMvZDKFfGH7Wqp8ziYa4qqCu1fuWU5n1N1Eixz5NCWH6LFZTSXwz0in4RcgJvTsdm1jo3epIoKnxBaXaFp1Da@XKlLgK/Bh0lck9hXwgg/kgfZSTBirHRyWhMUQHrkQ42ZDsp6Fxq1Ip8BIHJw0CH9KvgNaEYz5Q18psvGNb4xYpQJjbfXgsRQBYdVlvvGMare0rkbs1BoPLQrtMNayP7PxOhWtZXuDnjmFJprSpMj19XUbIB08xpVVeuUpWvh73SSfBrivJ6b0/3/@AT47gwpw505yUJF2THBmdpImOPnRRAx3PpblkTXBk9C4n1zxrF5bw60AZZlSG/KOOOqvItJVcE@Fa7bKuD0ObeFjymWr3HKbdEtTqaU13NZU80ZTkJyi/svRRs9tnkX9QBsvv8RtWWUjt62KNgD8zx9qPpFPZBNGrRqTi3K8WqM7vBSNNyN1YwN4zjJbKjzbrjPyVKNQuw6whOJh1hVpK455JbB8lwKPouM6wPomNIGeOyyCOlgauB4dE1w0GyDrQTiWRu6gmLqWti5VHqvdbl9LRbMNQv2yya3firKRzculamn2vp2TS7Vr6UHfatkmmsKfpi5vJMql5OsgzmkKoy2JlMNIUB5eDKg5fnZShWy2qiBlavvQeVRrO/6pStDNS4ahGmk1rat6Gv9vcRj4f/f4Bvwb@Aup0oZ0gjsLn0GdgDR12BM8xHnkshPXpfu6HlrNFTH2uiYZp@0NXc/7e8R5aDpnPOiRzY/zCYI@MfGgfq9vj7orYrwY9HFTojX8R4Ow328AgtgYeISH8DPsue6yCNvsxfMVpXwaHKAHxOAn6EH0o4OPPzkJPU/2d/c@kXLs4eGzRwuPrIiUZU/2H58Er9s81E@aDUB8ff/Jk8VX8Yhgv4vzpxssu@07dAmtW@/BqOOecGZzM2cKnS/5xivbC6wt@Q67onTi78YyGTbchsWafJ8oDoPoDAehDenbBUkaMMe9YNsp1nJ7PRPvKmxvgGfXxF0mFvbvPbpSE7O@cIe91oXdsjakp7ihpaDjhWyIhPQJAOmPm7Rh2h5JeCJQC28RxPn6Bl6EPsabOld4wgO90Dm0O12QnxeuH0FqmCaD74d@IL0V/ozWe4x4HuR3I6R3M7oUkVCNM0dmJF@6d09/PgTOruRTxWLHAkUfZF9lfwLcxcbsBfC7OUSJuZlkm1k515QfM60eMbdAderYVebVBkcsj7PITTOd2QJNVkc1ANQ309qOoJQF5QWVy6oBCsxpKmm2Mi6oGvJQdkpvWbMEymJdYqXiX//Wj5GVt5IgtSK6LKO57YYuaaQeGoV8Nl9IG9AFFPKZrJ7LZhO6kQDte7uAHYSe13P5bEFP5DOFdAb0LQjNFralCLdlSm4RSHgWAazTxKvEdkjD1LoVKcLXcdjbmKmwiBm8j5lsQRoZL4/2RrSfb8suy0aG6SkGgwuAaLImizx@vJd6/FiWH@ILrl7vpWS5hS/ZfCq1/VCWLQrZy2O/Kbs8TR5PZJBH/CWVergny2MOAA8zlOUuvuzncG5Clm182dt9/BjzaeOLgekh2hkP4S89/2Ubojn4kk7T5IYsvwnAQbxdnlGGMN3HF8wTQx7zkD0Ik@WPfXxSKYBwxONxCJ/4Zd3dleUD/rK7iyF7VPAsR/VTfNmljywDi2AzkeUOODpDaKCy3AAnNhZZboKrOTXBDy9uwxPvnJEpy1NOICSRLE8ottk8k2EAL/wxm08@@cTsjlpWh3@mQ/5sAmoQYk/G@48bH3/c6HQaw@nu/sdHGLK394nZno6HjU5DJGvU4eNCGgg5608XP4DjQb1u9paGfAohzkJIfVq3ELe6@QZwEp8OZtKv70HIHoQsWwLj0ODTh6gN/Dzsw/Oh2aAQ/0Mh9Jw0GnIJGRVVN7p9FdoMXYSa6JvNoVvC90l5g7FoLJqYVnOpWokCWB@UtFTpmq5djdFt9zgYVi6n1Uk5VStPytsGt51ox@TTiZG15cRG/75eyBY3zPu6kYlPirir121HWVTV77OYfm/rLYs9U@4b6UxRPr1/X5Wreu2@oeeLue0vtsayrBTx9356uwgRU1EYKuKPUt2u3d/OhpJsb8fNpFHc3lZK10COEXSmDZQj9VjswjLPFAXRxSENFIFf@jqlctqldmySmJQ5XmyqlCZlvcQPY2KpG7BaePLfuDlyhxxiB8BN7qeKdK2srBfyMuSfTMYUBSQTCRF4ziyjXn7t5Ozk5HOQWTBYFEOt5/yuwpJ4/fiTPQ1GX@INT@zTHqOK7A61PRQscyH8QDnf6wTEp/YJ9IigRvt@uNNi6Pa0/QkMgFFF9QP8c5g0cXqOdvLJHJxjGGfynHGjaomOYHCaFsMDDe0WM8sVcJktGOKTuDOVC@qL65VKuV7u85thK0GqTxmd9jcDc@Bx3IPts5T8EncfiIB6OXVdapQnkQnAqZeZqr/qu61XRrxZauE5hg/LDzFxqQ7PRskqW3g/rhyRS@37Dozax45ntq3n1hA3gx8cbkKHg1sSYm1mKZvslG7T3UPV@VqtDJkzw@zZuB8z1UpDmfcKvSJpYl/zi3xJe2RwUfm61C6z2BdK6Q28DjdZrKU9VO5nSq3YQ1ZXwCf1qv2qzQyWy5TogrEYQoJGRLShW2qVcuVTUGY44LNiERARdXwGMDEnAGu3KMBUBvZ1qVnusZjKJkwh8mRKnXIVU1/hz44qyzVVrV7VpIqqvpQq0E5L04hZ9sYNOvyWpRq6kcqVJuCnb2dKXahY84tJaVgewEi81INXMe/AtwKZJSAnUA3AvL2Kvf/Fbyo7arbM/UoE6qoH@kNdq5cnJQeP0wCWKKfLEBCvZlKJbB6GZtntBHTIBvT0uUQ6kUmo2@ir03gNPHXo@WO9mMyYnEhNUpqe0C09Aa3/ld16xZTEWQxUDyIZvIzcfbycF3ygkpAr6RWeJlPixlaPQS24zNxRiU1BUpSwYEDzLhvYiS6COrLMHqVQFJWlt2K9zRjG2TwZD/artWJxfzL4GgTF1Df3c/HtVPytopRiG0rZs95IlZJUQalCpR5sAM@KKRnmjftVqOPRpr5tFKvVBpZwO5VIp9JQPLt@1dmRK3ItkdrI6VBD14z0GMYFBtdlZtrIzK@OCjTedM30glGSNLI@oBz1mFFYtYdEkdDuTQCUBkLYIYVZ7FT2N8PFotFtIxpVoiWcvN2QxZwbSDh@aTaI2ug9/b4M@hOMqAsGRpgJStrvlAqrUNcSDphZpiBFLqXry@sdGGEmyQwNNEK2QS5VqzyQIkXGQI87FSdqJDcY@1DrtvhO5Qv@PEX7V4Ar0XFYVVYjmxPLxmER@wz3dt5nUUDMHParhpGuVY1t6N9AZvpRDUMv4dR0BA1ttQpQ3rsE/HbiFdwW8SmbTs246lP2HmOd@KZEhY4skn23vNs52i35b3s4LXYqybJcisqRy2gkeg1/UuQB7cUw@F4MFgntxuD2m00L6PMuQhKD7V36EyZFvJQhZha5fKjWlHfP7N5lPq3yIT4IrOvryGaSakSYtJc@fWVkoY4c17dxh6EOKt3QdWWzOLUXSb4aeN8w8umnB4fOo@Fji3ET93ymLlciLKWraDFeKgrfLDdxlQt5QzbOEhH2IFKKsDM1qhfJDJ4NjgtfbH@R/@Lpi8MXh4@lyOnG1YaL077MJwt753z1axAxms5EGTstRyblTEmYGVUqqr5j4Ok12wxvPm/rOTV1VeHsW6GAnAEh73/xNzKTnTy8G6C9FqEKs3GjUtG3DKZEBu@//H08pOBy/7PdJyzqmVP2d3/yI2P77/7kX5PxTvS65NHk4nYEYqJTz21HLi8Hl5fX8OFh2UgtwpHKbCvg5vPZemRmaV9MmubWdjxjPHBKSRFX39aViKdGxKz9djbiXYkgI5WHIH9anbzkHFZBZP/Izhr6gx1kCj3YoMNmq7eWVwCuyD99dcUYvDQrrU7HNsiVTLLiO5XtvFN32Ducln6nbrBX5Qoupeq4rcefgd2qVCoIhUUr8eRWlBlZCKtel2pxRjO4MO77wtpytk7nOfp0gxUKDvhb3paY@D/d8mBwt@XQn7XlefDqv1lbrz0m49JEMtlq0ektOxbLVqD@t5KAzqny/hd/3TByf/cnv3JVv6p/bsDIrVDI6UbkZ/rPfgYR1uwn94ddNE2NG7/REQzX2IpberUmjBTx6uY24/H9wRsO11BnsDsODM3xTTpHPYeqps4PKWrFKNoWbjdNkNZMR4goJUkKtEvSioedZoJgsC08QR3apnQpfQWDoDNlZRCX0ldmoMCjD92n26x7vfFwQObrMUqn1xLsHiSBHL6CJ0Jt0DZZIXNVEFPJrZtJOcoeUY10Ita3PA/Pl4JeRPoKJBGnXeHFsCbu6MaYtgNCXsMohCcFtKqQdw3y7vEEdfKNUel5hATj2PFEDmjO0ldAGSAq2KAjMHsHIpRAsHwFCABliAnAdo3tsLTCLu14vDQ7vOoaTYHxxC/T300qYTKE1sLdy37iEsYDL9DY8X4V5AtRw6CehTx9IBwGX6osg86PyekNlS7a7n1nUACLjlaJUdHYvXszrMplu6UwKhHCP7MHOAFF9eAsxxWA@eOlj1pFOcHwWLCS7xuwHVA8TugC16n8PLBSKCmT8fVakuD/zkyLHLlQVRRQwgKI@uKtogkkg8RIdl6HTbZTZrqxrbAA@Sbg3iSk6OCpYBB4OvlIMz73A68Bw59F/NOLQfqchCf1BN8ubidm0O2N8ehYPFSGCwOxDZgfG4NS7GDkpw5SQVHsHsVu20MYoNBSqX8GVSytK5hsdmYX4UHGvUaGoZVtVsEHpcLYDJ4mnrYk8tmgEyOaLlSoN3AdOp6JjpJAA2bgCJBR4pQbjvbYucCjxkXdUOIwRh6dcIOcjxjTcVN0RxulxbXHxhBGsT5tEszqaKzZbzGjwGLEaHQajxOAUygRIdwAbRdp3OhZfUDp2LIYnlDkFZPJDmhF4wYdSfTUBr7qPrahK3G8pLgOL3lhn9nJEzwqVXXboEKLDd4RVKSw@fFlTnH8T891z1jPPrP4XG1sbnu8x0DfB6U1AZSdfYGwRZwWNtIJloLgBI8F3214bHNnPhFKuxGbKjefaX0jVscavaI@yR7iVXfnphOiL32uJDHE9aaef8AGHRMB71ogci2xtb4cxV29wZkRkjgqpEynVGg4Xz@IwYDTP2IDnaCLW@cMB6sS9jEgNJv@ZnVsxVDar1AHQG0PWhaetjUaFvGIBcBk2Io1oekJAe@wj1jakDAiP/9EnFUCMLDqy/PQIQySYjm8UQsqRuMbo0CuQOvstyAMN/cK9sP0Pnejm05Cm7E32xDgsNOhvMqMNwv/JRt6wdaB/ExF34DAHGC4BJONmBwHsHFZkTnoIP1ics7tEsmSIrsJKcEQgiA1QCFVwb8Lk4XOBJcg4KHp8YMjxblcFxcXGh0QNx7amuXhOdkeXvCZHHRs0Ind5MjqD8SNRDbeRCfgzlwqPx4fr329P6ELVwv3pvwpSW2vLIwSYtG2F8XO8RyPge706WAZPNHFI4Z6bNMR8s2YsKPg/GfUEpc@/xWR/9R89BqBMIZgJolpopkAYIlG8yzRvmiVRMA5NUgADrVo@Z54KOPQf@l7vssetIMY7oi2C/jvjd4ZrVcCJJlPnc6y5iX0Y079V/E@sCeQyLEu2O5waE5jFK5gbGTg2JTUHjaFbp9CwAndDLvkJwTak@q0Npd8EiSHTs0f8rAhnhojXa4Hyo@LxPAJD59A@ISHT2aZ@tlWJzWukqHXNRYHuR4PG/NjIpipH@eaH604CyHIoFgznYPAmNM5v2v4NsuU2qc3f4N6LPuMATwxAIJbsWT1i9Pqac3xrIutWjzZAWaXiRBQ4wC6WiOaXrQCN1K/d94buN6cl4NnzEGvJPBGr2ZXcAPnFSxjUEHEGJxeNh4L1umLpXKuEIgCAwTUwyAQVYPdUcxWSsGBpRQIjFOVZzTmiFUFMjXSvkSQ8AN1iZOeEzYMqBYChP5BkQBNCGF@y@G3IvjS4eUQL3/246p0kHsfj6eJ1qJAyYWmwmVNiSophJWq@mgC2VFdLS8WxQ@HqqguBIWKeS3qP4z@xgej34Z2sRx7YljeYZSkcFNBKy1QIURzIaqySjlUr4BBcsvsWUPoufa5fip6a8hmK@kPM3g@WATvAq96jIUqv6nw@qENXLIjFwNWmJbLUMRpmTdL3i58knKCB8k8kWzqM4JIzwUIwEgtTWaJZJNwskm5zAUHm6xIdhFCckJITngSHnuyAsmaSAajp@COYKyeGminaBMmAzydd6OgBg1khvc94rL0azw6C1cpRZ4zmUNcIHgIVWzks2Ztae7VENIhobUAABnxBoAWv2CpKC0KPF0N3gIZxUnpyyj@JtiAywpgMBLBJX68ZCxgMhoDg8Ivx6kfgLYrx6uSrNO8Lv6l@FdO@J7@V7/pmZqPqc97@nY@wd8/imcNKRtqoCHtQ09lUCDjSOaFuBl7TueI4F2EXRe0usaFy2JLlG3wT/qXaicbPbeR7JtoCoLXrgRXbSv@@AHXRNiDgTsyR24mU@SDJpvYbln@fMxgdxwXhibhY2VB12u5ludER1CpTbfj2J6VwMu9ucpukWECP2BbCuvJwul6kiTmIPkwFkFzvkJVt17Hi@Dq9RjafinFwJyUTMGQPaNRCce/4AqlB/EkgB4OYm7jtdUcKbfDxBOQRbITu3kWOxyIwChksstAhjVB/4fQLmgwzHNnI0c6ixVV6cYoRse4d92@2wGtb@xpEqZeAH8wg40ImYMB4ZJgJg5pi6FzsKmVxJoJUxFJP/3gpOxTI2YqQXpjHsAcMRJsuEhjpOxwSXb1ldnxZH5@xx@O73EY3@P1@NIofBFnPjQv88APyzodm0GAiDM00rejgUUHudW6gc4cKoE36lU8wZ1RbJGpVQsx3YWouyK61gb@SARvHrwFiH@2iv7rK9BPvn/X6jPxdszjKcibPloAxuiAfc9f3IxB9ANFkSJLsgtY@9Ed84K4eLfJY1QhQI0lweXgMZLQMAcw7PaCw819wLfwPFpM3eB7MqMq88AlOA3PE@zMWF1Fj@otq2dOrVZMxEyE4PolPoIBG8mruxUcBR0JPZeP9WLQdylBKHTjSHQeqbiCZczEuaKsZisexQ64h2bKCcOD1fTD8BuiGaf4yny2GsYB0Sgeaeac2zj9OZgOpvyk4h6/F0HIUd7/8JrEbeq3EwToIA5qScyyVdaJz6NYUKQ79AhBXG2@yHiQqA8Rz@i8WYcfRqLbSwqVG0pU9mtZmj91f3mN2@tqPMQVPk/ydaO7seRtTHdnnguxGgc2E2F7H9aF3ICM9hjNZiwMkfusrTHXuSET0I/m6ZwVvUp9iUANUpKkG9k03Cb9QpFwZHwAT5xw@gyeCLBjjeqcofyy4ZyWuLCEUUjfHIS0FuEDSjpACVGRk1ygEYol@W6Ifnkd5NlcmWfzRp7NuTyDFjCfZSiS1JzLUtQCVs@6KuhZ7dEK6YxBOHaGxzqxDR/HNYc4W3EZtaNFO8Gi59EiCOSoFS3ux0AoR1vR4iNyeNHiMTnOosVPwTFrW9GraNFvFhhhCK/keID@QoTjezNa3Isp19LIPLM8P18tWgzqFOLc569EESAFlhu0Rlxic1xRzNHQgo6NlMoEQ47xEjh8onmYBH1T8M/v0aDz@DEQ5zi3KDKLM32u0wj1GDwf6Db8856XtOSi6M33Dx@TPVMQBbOJwxgvnIbAgxoeic4LI44YhtKKBjwBQZSbxeUYsVBPdkd0RO7AoVTJ8/kT9TTSB1oxCq9C5NosE7o8RaT362seBK/Au@GJiVfheQMdPzvCCNdklSVoIVFfRdcUCut6HhdR@@Eaornu@Uh4vawfhdcSgQ3JdNDhaHEOMxu4g3kmoVA0grfDaWhSjjdK5N6FZCQVRMtcEUzeomQoGMKNX1lXnFA6RG1OBGFgNVXjrSzoF0gWY9BM1oU0Vd74AIWQzIEWbjXP6GKaR8JJ8bi4SVBfsaob8tPyLElyzYtJSKzheTtjc8RzDwav@3gKz4cNX/2UE5xriSGAUMogFy5f3Q/Q312uv/sKtU@EhQyWKdbLu9Kb6vXaXnYB894s25sViIEJ9khZqhwFOcxIDqODkGa@jtduqPho8sGVfJ5pAH1B2/fJFowJbqHb4tiCw0ItYXg@73lmgOeZsZpQNzWS3rnmKy0a5iTg8IIHmM6Kth5XXvBlVYwhNL9t9j64gofzFRyuPIRHBRgukJy38uHYISuXWdsGsc19UKTqRcYFOS2XBtU88wRxT0u3wbIteBzWjx4dPnvydeh0t7e3FdFHT2f4YavFudagH@eQyTg66A@WDFuMBN41gYvdOB1PVzlvnDryDVnChTUoAybk4rOfaOOKkGUheb7QdiEdjxuiqIB1NmsG5pxUQlXHxC7bFnQdAUGsUWzLFEB89RbonaDRmkK3KtTreH1vvU7dV72Oxkv1uujFsGr8FXHlZ5GN5Ngb0vWB/EqQC0mijfLs0SF7@cnuCTv5ZJ89frH3Kfv64Qv2cvfZCW54fv7i4ZODPQbf/WfH@0yaM4/E65NwQAl0fWQ1Lbz3Dg8ryzCCvOcOplzuxPYU7n9s9tknbtPCZaodz@w/6PIXzbFGFZ5qH4ajU5zDtOmKrL49QnsLut8JhrGo3LRokx3a8jOI24AxbR/HvH23ZbdtiCvh2HdgW56/14v1bKhBkLf@xtQEV5LwKicyHaJL19AC6wKSmxAf124AjMntr@iGZNvjCayWxgThgs8HU/Bk/@jpMcMt9XuHzx4dnBwcPjtmjw@P4PX51w@efQz0PDg@OTp4@AKDKOLTw0cHjw/2dsmDI5DSGG5qfz32RmtR0DA6UaV5hivfdBF28DY/640aPLswabuhx6JjB6WPbfbst1YrWpLGHqovuMWRlgpYbHP36OPPoM9n1htc4fSXgsn@QH7h0ZVimym2Q7lBY6lAeyuJ5grdnqortB7RnzK8YcAq0f71GLkTzAdORjwt22LyHtqo4Nw33@ZObdkHDRltAGwE5RuslBndDBKNJnYIZAVya/ZcPKiQ58aNCMULJn3gm5qUJKKYsJVBoLhf4cDB@SC9FHgA34OHIbIdDXkElg48eASW4R6oih6g7QjLihjj0eEYxTPLcY/X/cFjWhZm24HHQ5NGsXmBE683qlKTBTcr4ab/Ht3/wmd56F4602vaNiXxKD7ejdLr8YZh8Vu5QCbypUSybYOYMgibNi41CLM3fqElhgI3oJ2Q2R55LFZWNHaCxkGWY/Obdzo90@EmUDPTHeI9lsdjXcrCzNYObqyhHSADlxgQb8uaxyNI90hohdZd00HKhzdyNIWNJN0a55ug3YbAwxsI/DxgAJA6N9JpUk9Fu0oRjNsWrBzzXOBInLd9F44P7NwaN625BMJqK/bafvtWEUROzI2TfDtFwg6q6K01BLWSljLb7hDaOIlVuuMDpWCz6w5GNq/D2HwJaMWJujmIjR0b5PaqXJnLDemwmKPjOqFMG8DFK3JtAFPeJVfieL52Hoiv2YWPwPnQCXO7O0THbOBF0LO1swQuIl1YOP0CijCtlePk53REmHD9U5rJjncM74zLlyuPHp6q714l8OI4Lhb4XY2@0SF@gTExL2getM5HBotD1LtES/Mv/PHGDUwtbPCEtMRW7gODcWDXhnHdg3opCOPmxjf9cY/Moj95Xl2VeSoVJZO4vtPrxmbSLcGqfpYJSlNjwgQkJDsBWZD1Md8nQTADef0A98VgLZSAIg7KERy3L1ynI0SIX7rGuA2SRdxqKKo7gK@wCllUzC55xZ0t4fpIfhF7WI5XlOTMoISFyBnzRXTCh6wrSsgshfqrG@AerQcH8vvu4PJrsePdwwdBe7QW2gfhpsZXw@LdUgjW3cG@WwOWd24/F1goe2I1YN5J3oQWcHrAnInNSGBNuz7HVzfqjtoegMG@F2dQAqCh3MYOLVH7xwLHeAIlDGamEB2fPNo/OmIyH59AWpB7OGRoCTGIsDfY85m1re2QsNMCpSkYLAfKk@8zZ9Hmf9Y15qXEWyEqhA6SEPQIhMXsOuO2PeFST/QspEKQ9T0JRJ9y89hd@jLIqwrA1zAGBGRnlRYqoLS0mBHe@dhe2Ahc0C3BdeOwDT9ZWPO@G@8KHE7DgMI2QWYHd5Ysr7@XXD8u@vlwBct6M6YCt0CThv4GxgnHkPEAImrafA2uqRa/StHInivYEZ92aPiVmtew//4MRYzElXCuC4fEulCOBWpcP9701RwySMRuwERLTxHILZohwBfx5LMTrlBl1unF5rsgUDLx9rgHYa6A5LXrUnCfeWzWT5YDhTzc1jYJm6qPZQ1nZwXs0upIH6EtdG5RPCxmBdJ2bVbqP0xWvJeYy8mn@dLC@IEAOZfNpm@DvVgKP7n694XN@5BF@TnqD2B8PwPpTT2a3gfOPXiW8MNnDLCGdNy03m8wCwlB1VnSp8yVnTqjMH6AC58XAmTwOG68kG8xV4VNFnBbDp33SGHoFOVGGUJNOCgobzU3qH@9PjsUyLfmt/Hh@fHGhpHQdPAarfKfukPPmu3KC52iEvLC/avzftZw6FA0vp/p/ynu6rbaSJL0NfUU6RI2KpBKEjYYI4RbgLDVg8GDwG6OwOpCKglNC4lWCZDasGd2L/YFdu/3EfZV5h3map9iNr6IzPoRArtPX7TPMaqqzIyMjIz8i7@8BJQ0uzE96WzH3nZi8CqtQiLr2@ItaWvvJDG7zRhZA1fC4kUXd3BCulecFu9lC8V4U3erexW1yGHy2glZpD20ndjc86zbfwoBnoNZLoHlg334ngfr9J9wyBiQRCb25kszbZxv4sYUoV1zna9I0Wahem4tTPd@O2h6fYT0yNjPA2VnXlBBlsJWDnadWZL1fDFRnpALrvppKpWxs67NRekbBLqAlAQhvYnvsQULnhrGUvKJm9O9XGEtv/rG4tb1M6PMZf3NWWaxWbIVLb5e/zK4Ht62fukMLm7aqqeu/nY@bk5@@1WplVfqJdW1/EJCpBZWSzmOL/ma/q6pN3nmXI3gWw73emor5cptbUotqOgcXnym5KYyPjSvw0NiikvV4qXhQrjYjUqX9dWzUr@UL17W@2dFOPmNlkqjpcJSGh9e0CpKc4xo5uujM6ypcamr379RuMSTL1vTriGKXUPoywdv2B3slfffJaRx2ABABKZtvVmgLvdvzsGaDb4nbt@/TWsxWUaBYy1skKw59goqwKed5ckQx7S6hBn1SoZ2s8GY/04cay7vXl@NBpxi4uqBtdRd986aM25MeZYoUJZ698ygs8FwojxpKIbk60SsqLMF2a4V4DvpxEDUUZKnQ/vUtuFTCES1L1f9zApc32teAAlcOHvHxdTGBl8/S6wWuCzFgymHN2SHifwZHqEAoZ8r1jagCt65B@z2YVHz8V7Ag3xhGdWI/WTYQN7inSJSYP6tvrJ/E5ffIAII4edkz@VqEafeedFGUnwHWbiA0GPJgz/UDHCrlE6ZQ2MBW@orRcDZUpxphGo1mej73C3IKbSif7oF2QK/PWhGmN@R7EwS1lPrtwC05C7lpE389KJi6VixrClmMsdIMfdNakDSRcejDz4Nq4na9ns9QlpoMReRA4/s36vrXwrrD@qo8yxEXtKzD9KziXRX0gWpKJdLC3yUaT2eyU59jfLdKzvKlnlQV0nx5sWlnm66tCWJ8hafyhu4o0GjG2XeDLtSuDJM2EgkZGMpX2b0vqQ8S5QJGTxMr0u65u9l3fMhlom8PyTrx6@lO8hn41ltazLFpW6/23sri1aYAjaziZpKSXH0N7OdDErtg6mnE9rBQc7Pw3azFEFZKpgZh8eMvbnxg@3qTcbb9DQa4sX4YGDNGCMxKnGdS0y4MTssUj2c/CwGgmGC0ZQZuZum8EQXnsTAItczU614QT4Y4NS06SFegl/kHf6YwZ5EzuRLzU6cE8zH0njxbk4SiCfdZ/ZsMiVnE7iLyEfdqCdWkajuyTTE2ZPEfkwKHNbpiw92G2LwZ@E8EZ8ozEzxgO5hiqZ0lKFg2PexLkTivfWv3KL1zqM99lXPH6syjhkee2FZCQf3kR@MAsR24lg0wfXVVQ9aR97w3bILtQ4UsrwCdUsEMbayu1YVlj2SP4Mn7ZBOhVx1AMi3MBCJEoLrTgfOZPCAHdxiaoXEpTtyrXJ/IgINGjMvl8XN3FfXgWhN6bTfiSMhPSejB5QOrrym71q0Rwto92NJU9syvrU8HX4jiB5GS9q6Zf31utv8Zfsd9LmvC/mXhRjJbrQ6OO@@fBU5WBGRTMJynraxK4VXlhXTDTdFN5wFwIzaw0L/iXjTv/H7fd8q04rBGQPatAb@8MZvuZZ16IdKYMAFK0MzCT/swfWwKcId2nR5xIzwEg4yog4jDsMv1mdRFzdZV5axoLSKtM3U1TfdFghoPE7aA2iHWWGBMAFCDxS69EdElEVHJVFi3bPGhfculxBEETUQ5ySmmwjJ0B@Muk3qGZZkWT0CJWqQqLJ@awoTqq/Z8@Ac7M5CAO4xEQUMAkaV9BQOllaa/y4clG6Y0bF7pmdyNPsNeKzQcPeHXZp9IwJzr3CxGO7UwUfvqzVVO9g9@lw@rCh6/nh48Km6U9lRWyes44ainGPYqvcHezS7hNp00Zof0Ae7XKOSNidY5f0TVfnp42GlVlMHh6r64eNelaAR@MPy/lG1Usuo6v723vEOa98Jgto/OFJ71Q/VI8p2dJDhWk0xKyqnDnbVh8rh9nt6LW9V96pHJ1zjbvVoH5VBq19WH8uHR9Xt473yofp4fPjxoFZRaJi1U61t75WrHyo7LtVPdarKp8r@kaq9L@/tTTX04PN@5VCxkUCslVsVwrK8RUdY1MTt3KkeVraP0KDoaZuIRwjuZVTtY2W7iofKTxVqTvnwJKOB1ip/PaZMlKh2yh/K76hxVvobVKF@2T4@rCD@EShRO96qHVWPjo8q6t3BwQ7TulY5/FTdrtSKyto7qDHBjmuVjMI1blw1wSBqUTo9bx3Xqky36v4RrRnHH2Hv4FAnfybCEJZlKrrDBIYZBFpLRDo4PAFU0IE7IKM@v6/Q90PQlKlVBhVgUbF9FM9GFRIRj@LNVPuVd3vVd5X97QqSDwDmc7VWcajDqjVkqMIg44RYhyo95lajnwgveSRmtQznZrg7VXVXlXc@VYG5zk0cUKtqbmGybb/XNHcRDTcmROkOIDPwLuOClfbDTzc@gks@lMjMltGEEZO2D3YqtCLrYFV2lHBMq87aVCileBqtNGEivSZC1rT88@tOo9tvD@BjGhYTwcdl0MngPhQH10KcWk9cO6HlK1wglWo0PpUbdNCtNRpO5ntKJtD4VgktBn8ql6PbiHj3OHlD8LO@LnTfSBBq84VWdLKhHhQQyCnUfyGmb96l76hcruXrYnDeB2AjOgpEbXIBVQpNjezsiLsroipZMsHvXc0OXDBtwLvNBuSksIzkTIOA/vTvohdZHGIfaHYWcVcuh0Mso9H9zTfVSCUcEoH/6IgE3TZX6Qa@/0snnY9XhzO/2xkMWmnHMWU474jOgZ20843i535nqnh2ujwjy2pnHTM/MOdu3sKE@mdNMqX7xR1yy9L40xjxj2OwkZgPkJpyVSys1kLL9AspDoukjNKhLeBewZ2MPd@H8k/VzzjN5ZdfFae@vw@/y9iCvSCC0NKCV@dyZ/zz/kwy0ADjWBxEkq6OkJHLxcoYe5Mw8y1lvECm224Llj@0Vl/4vK4TSWgje@314nViNR52x3HsaR5@d1j@sHW8u0tTJ7B9tbbyerVohWG3fsrI7wnq4UixHHXsitZx2qdxUmyUbNPGh0dKLJZ2xP7MwLkcMiKeuuk0/og4D6HdRtKSCRMZmhvgIpc@TPRsH3SwFQfgeGYZfp05MjUDpBNNddCaS2/MW3yP9krMA9qYpTfhXhvjD2CHw98M8bBBmoE0i3HsXOJcOl3wvGfvGlNRPtxw4B5kcW3DxxLGLaQBi7rYfhbetfymeTvWi4GYMmK8crdzSULi2TQWythV9GVkf@Q4I1oAzNHD6MtPmt/o8UQHuONwd14wKo9qRMbdsCTk1JEwWje6riGfbZaoi168CGvaUJDyOxopHntanBwGBomNBkblDEaFJTUFuBjGEZmuki1gf1hw1FfhVATvAJyi5lj9Tpw7qzkaStHED9HvJiqFElhhkBOh2m1Yh2WynIRxLAw5E2T6Q/Rg@H8iTWbA36ATJ0GPqBULAvhdlGSoQis6vjJRurdG0RDTbkTUjH86icDcxzvmImyY1t6Mxb@GSKB7Z2I@nHDYw3Z6BgHA5BBsxMdvaJJ24dHR6Qfb0cWhJ@k3L6/SSq8VZql4ADe7epbhbVfG6Fbw4ihHZE2xCveoqPpBDm7nPOrpyDR1lFfPA1vAOSb@R26RBSDhgGcuvRCr1WnOyutRZuYBHWoptuC0wohJtC29f1Rrt6hiITITc7/WfBlCEehN4POwnXzRx0CJeW4y4iKvxOqIo@AhHjiOyVh8dMi6czbE7PmA87zFwhDcBTK6xQLRE@gcqi@CptLP2VAElURWh1GcQUy3jkuk5WX1NsSeJZPg0BD7474EovdFqmVyuBLgQ2MYd5d31QdvQij3vq/ZwmK5xdogA9tFVCZiCV0e9540B4MhbR09tJtwzHQnjqs@a6GD3w@uhzp@Ia1n3aGWSJhNP1WDbZOc3nmZkRjwjFrQHcFboeUyf3CTLn1YiEp4knF2VaWJeQ2PbhqhY3e8VFDpjShlg2jCYUmZiBtqVd3dSS4hqA4Z6jMFu0F4uGCbTa4Heodw@N0Ohr9g7ccWqN/yW2Fk0hhIlgVKJ1X7HOOxOZKmm4ueqCsgAQkpURBBWmioSmv0a81O2q7JjqJjInYpt@T31xMyqbGWoooixtW1E/OtZqkzQaVlHRo0DBZaWF5hVGYduO4fPYxxtNCk2lrZp/1wSlmXTUTpudk64knmzfDpBE9ayF96HmD00BfouPUWFAhjzwq96sN5jvGDTcHnrj9sxWWitJNpeVcQv/HRZ9BnXjSiQx32r@mNAn9CJ4BmrjvOMYxG@sfBRb@xPeh5ne6g69E5DWHcxzLj4XHCj@iwznBwG/CVPpzQimVqTaJniS8jYdjwHuoli7HQXMHIv0rHzRRGw0n5QsJEsOQcRoDRhYzM31fTMdLCMq9WokJW0v@U7fEKTvHRsi8LswqLRh8A9AS3OWVBIT6kI3ZMijmfFh9kOH8qQwzHc5VVnvOIxV4C4zdEIlbDJDA2yDwwS4g3AiezRzGut8aZFscgHCLQkr/j48qZIM2fMx6uvqVZ5C0sBdZVYS0fKypalDHiEOJh8ji5l1//ydgTAn8A/cLLWdwyixF4imubaEuBnFd0lFHChc0DuzxH80xMs1i3Q6tQLwG0MZ6GmkyePEYNtvyhTZEOs/eAKzEi03TwwS1x6QZNOY2Jg0VlQS04HLcDW5DyKJ1/nGH9b9nP8uCHElckZ5iYtjXkdAzpx0jVJCrhls8p89o4yhJT@dsjZnn5e3ttioClWSZnsdts07bZubAHSlfWV6i1BkOajO0p6mlTj4VgNLha@E7qPTp3zIzMNovWTcf5piGwMFuJFsvFFpO2NMHjpGhN4zPFNEmKsaUZ8RCOr/wcsvk0EcelBsZbqTH5Bh0eo1lkNxUuKmF/t2TsY1G8gUWvWWjCIcW4I0hpMfxeb1DDG4/PIBqmHK8aPGM0MGU0JvIYAzVFppBK308h5j6N@xQ9WkQ51Nsi2sX751GiThvJmZCnJikR5BL0ROB2OG3SvHTVhvEFwsTJDjecpMIN5zgzYVVeIXuOIMNIEIDYFfvZSA4lEtyos6b4iG8HaKcbsBYqYCaip824hUMY9D8kGEfl18IdbfHQmGQLZ0WBNA4h0amCcz0Fyfib02u9MWYoD0hBQ3wGKcIWPZibLr6/VX@0LZSPIEhpTtaWvvkMGuOoJcKG/sSTGmPsgaOqdMnEiEoOhAZPDTQW6JTS6flyXMXurzsUjod1gx5GdICQz2n8LOkSCOe9mg@pjSLj1gRZHE1uGW2Oym5KkYih5B3k10NRtrp8cCUAvmBM5UsFgoCwpow9lAIceifOeQlEdR9RwVIBw5I@clTUyM5zRjqIqjO8WonlyM/K8SYOIzsTCG0sZueJEKE9y@wsERRa6GbiEsvxenZ7ohy0ITa8LxSnrtC9kqRh2HNCQHpkbMMZpV5QmbzmYE58teIkEkP@5tQ3@VhqfjqV6BNiWM8WplPX8onURLXLy8miiZJEDydeayKRSOHEEQ5nhT/2j11T4iHPQ5vQ2CEjscvQ9tl9HKVucW5z/xaoDXbKNnsMAy/uGW6OXw25YiURlP3pAOxqgVUGiN3@h1trLFMNJvquAI5LZ5xd0nIg5B2rjaUezcJJ10TaCwMUmDPtoK0@He3uJsK@nk@ModGlP1zJ5/Ng4vN48HtjWw1RUneQS@bOta97vdzV7Y/DT@c5nvtx230vGKybE7RPXUKDInAHw47cDAEcKCtyZ7UjK8761@12/AoGaCjRedRtklNHQ1C8AHVDo5dPRywAYpB6gf0ZDUT7flbh6Lv1ZKOpoRg1FJWGSfCNbbRnRB58aMM@O9RUMTBMzMaaidYtp7T5FSsIbjbhzuLwxc7XyDzZfu/3eoOM@oxLgREpYO5@usDubrxAXrJAw8jevdcBx6PNKP@m24v5FSNLnNcBzixM5p4JExcesfEP/U5lfJW2619sWlaoyUto5hLiU2eU3bEdHSz@O8AKHxLa35X70rtKN5lO05lpqdcjOHoijF4WMjPPPoksDsvENM2@nRtEnY2uy8EaqOkO7wVMLHvuXm7JI9lD4tqn40IbNMwLDI0TYq58Xwm4mv150@LNqN3@vlmRrwGQjv1dM6LchPLHJkTWAfAI1MOP6Iko2n/J0rDenQooIhscXNbxcN5BgQYKWNbzZunX23S5XFbzV0tLqlzeoodsVpW3ymoHH7a21A69b@H9RWl5ZaUoc@6O85U@bpmP92qLYLCEc6l5MdyhV0orwW8M1tro4vlcaT5TnG@UNjaLQa5e3oJbPz3989//85//8V@5sn75H7xs8Uv9S5jJdd3cfPPr/Iv7It7rO2cL8@f1@auzhU4RXPYvjho@qI6yXmQ@6g7PrZSsArGvbEdqztkcfUYXVeZWv0tv@AvNLusq1QxyKf01kJujeI5NNf3Ydx9@lOd0hDeXDkwf5QmJFAGdQBxPvdP0YYBH6w1RknCBHaiUF92KEdwjHEyYIdSqpHQkHt6z3vjwaYkiKcAXl1asbLcf@H1IwG94zyvNsyyPfrujhubf3JcPQWdrMFaLp2m1mFeLGbVo2/xTWH1DX535XBfeuZKNjgO2naGUSLUAM0MVdHmjx@cHvmtnityWNc9X9gCSCVPBmcULLhOe/thZRi5cCzrWHC7NVCIiYSUTiqS@zvfvqVu@Uo57O@FqwxuFhj7FcGUxjUrYv9gCeYEYAkQ1XwpB1gdUJTR97JGMp5z5ovva4tuEGDDIevhul8c9PtBaNN/XNs@JsxSuOWLzefmKtbEoztCMNlKk/ggBVqjIcTLPnoQLqQVLrLxjreRmihd2vH2a@cTWYeKPjG26FPo3FWMCseaOE26@r/1atCG3qFeU3Q3VK7Gq7Gnbb2XFilxe90bdK@2uwLVjQH0Na7uXkYQeZUACR2L2rz8cYSwoMJGiprpFLsuaqNYATZeR0Neu6dTBjiuaoxgRcl/SNLbvpsa2k2MvEcMOwgOMVGjK1/a6vUBHXRkysTve8By3A3ptvlBtJHozlufhmtQpjAftEGmXIbPJeTSeqSmpq6HXufQyKrU/OBp6kyotW7TzGTVdh1qIEExAAoNPVz2reQZhaZHuEqZI2BS2HMLlBb2Jvh5N@tYOfU7QpWYo6LArGAQJdmJK@neJvpqiY8TVv6MT4ig/mLxDbaSeYnnmhaWRhmTH3WZ4mD0YOpapIT52woFjW4JqODINL@hC11hoL1nxSzN5DzECdN229gLUrgirb1A/VqeO3/cSi9NVzzKO/rmiknUR45mvohRrJMvcfFqIbrwDVrSP/JKMAiFrkwlnZM2l03Ongb7OLRVfRzjId2iLn/NUN7yAji8wY88QddzvymQ5tUJFd2C4qsqW/wSh3fM6hN/k1puAFU9T6bfPck79y2n/bDF92r87/c1hTPSUbFbZrEppZbaZsfRYoZUxl0m8Gqu0wIQaPO0nM5z2lfiwxEhAiOTS9S@5s7scIXSawp3ypykhSKLLgEnu6fpyAJ97gGYqiUUuZc05i47p/PTbgqNobeVf9KF8cOSXsDCHShbT0zln2CZQ7Kf767W4nAS5teX8q@XCKzoJdfxxduhfY73NBtfn/pi2EgGOs7T0nP6W4IYEIe7HgVekj2Nqp1xrIr4ngXZS0lOoHuZcjxWyFZVxhScoP1GZw6XCxcUJ83hQPuLAn1HEciYvx4IS08EY96WxfgaDS9TjBZjXpr1DhCNhZSA2IixCzQKyuXzlMQ51zHBZYD8nV20jdisDoe7NpWKrRX/Qz@rNmuMuFLGJhtdMby2/lp8eow@GaGKEzuvN1MIzVdh8@/of/33wa2qU2lzOfR7S7yj1a2p1LSWP9EBvL83bTWoztYFsq/epSY7OwPT4@h//S@U3fyQ4SJls0J/NFQNrdZLazJa4yF1qc5UeCsvLVO///f3v1IZ5ObHhLtb5RkYxYkVDkW2vz7xL6aqKVsqxdCGaVtgxCzDEwpDO5vQCw6jx8lqexXQpbVVx4@vIV8YeRS/xbJg1YlMhkWQYewraGUmBEirICkhjQtFWMdsNY7YB5o3QVD8/d1cDOgH8rM05wipD043nAUyG5uVYRB2YlhrpPC8Pm/m3dmjesW4bm5Ki2ULiaKfn2rWXxf8H)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/504wx)

Ungolfed IE6 code:

```html
<a>304</a>
<style>
* + body { display:none }
body { color:#fff }
a { color:#000; position:absolute; top:0 }
</style>
```

IE6 [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) `:after`, but the text can be hidden with `body{color:#fff}`.
We still need `body{display:none}` for other browsers, which is achieved by `* + body` selector.
IE6 does not support selector combinators `+~>`. `~` breaks HTMLayout, `>` breaks Flaks, so I use `+`.

Having the text in the same position greatly simplifies automatic testing, so I lift it up with `position:absolute;top:0`
(note: IE6 does not support `position:fixed`). Placing `<a>` after block element `<p>` lets us omit `left:0`.

Golf: `body{color:#fff}` → `*{-color:fff}`. Only IE6 treats `-color` as `color`
([link](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-1a8dbf9f026f452604757340923e4e62)). Note that modern browsers still support
[hashless hex colors](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-hashless-hex-color-quirk) in quirks mode (no `<!doctype html>`).

I placed `*{-color:fff}` below `a{color:000;...}` to fix Retina. This is fine because `a` has higher specificity than `*`.

JavaScript can be disabled in security settings in IE6.
IE6 seems to ignore security settings for local files, so I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

Comment: Glad to see you back and making answers on this!

Answer (score 6):

## 331. [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 14908 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@     <!--    (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####&:#######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//      n&goto e 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S     10  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnn M n M M M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$"*0;exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
:e
echo 330
exit




































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prs>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461!\0k:4op>arstdequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05r"93"在ｕ
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40XHh@REpULdIigRIgG9SpEqlkm6pb1VJLalu3b4UiwWSIIkSCLAAUiJLUkV3z26v2/bMenrajnbb49vuGc@21xMx3omddXvHPRPR3o8TjvnkH1B@bGw4Ntz/oPeckwAISiRV5UfExsZCIpDPk5knT548J58tze3//OcRfNihbU57pj1iI90dsY5jnOuOzB5M2X3NcHNqRhAw1LbTGw90a@SWhQhTGHNHmjNipmb1xlpPZxFwVdnM3jXMke4kmavrrKWb9gX4Zxiz9Au2b7WNDkBiI/tMt4w3ugN@WcYe6ubV4GrE2vZgoFkdlw0dwxqRb46xQw0s3XH7jGktd@Ro7ZFhW@CVZ@yZZWqDVkdjFHzo6DxSgQGo9hnFmfcpMvbEdlwdUrDbuuva6FgCR80x7MfbTz@5EV5Js080yNTQ1Cc3klcU9tzQnc7NGCr77GRv76Zrhn0q2Rbbu50lJcu2xyN7f3QTfo5t93RLY6pcktWbnnlA5kg3i@lies4L/PYMB2pT82qtPKsZazxo6Q4g36vCC2PUlyHCic0RzmzLnDJ9AsAgj10Ipo@YgbXFcuk0hoT/Y71tW50ZeHDSAQ7A1QfD0ZRJzLI9GgAv22HuUGvrUkc3jYEx0jvMNCB3dtfLjcugwtmZPr2wHah4iZMiZcQd6m2ja2AUrwSugMT2UG@Ne8wej4ZjyJ7LOoartUwI1pqyjt7VxuYoyVrgB8gj94u@bnlZMqweluP5zAUhWNAEeO7XFcCNYZoMsnOG2cGkXbaJHhfojkFbOuVS7yCo3Rm6AJJmun7p5xOeSwbjHTp2z9EGQKgdnXDw2f4hc9u2Azb4YVjeClaBaWsjtrnJortPH0ZZLUCj7LSEAKVVdskYi/ie7Fwzx7rLBtoU0rZG0LiYTfXnxxAgOIuuRcssmskwNc2yWZaFxlZkai7NoEmUwACtVs0o8MsztciyCtB9LprEdLqO1jNMnUPp2WYXARWQYtUcU@GdzrKMUowmeYg2pVNgmSLLF1ghxwrwLrGSCgkh1CxTSjn45eEHUEqQCwV@mSxPLSANJCkoBtthXW1gmFMOfThE8G2WU1gBIEJWFYCsFgFCSUUI808Y3qgPyO1r5wBSMo0zZBl6wDWwxlLwSW1spIhtIX/kSbp93TQxVUAWoClXZAVINQ8Fz0LKgEu1qPqF7/Wp@JSvQhp@kMcClLgIKE4DttKIrgL8wA6sSAWeowKDUYFnqAq4q2DOIFQIlwe/PNRXPutDVzuEW@CwEFdBZCJTURAHEA0qgWWgKvIsC1WcwSrOZRjkEzJQyDPgK0WFFbOsWGCArlKaAeoVyAzWvwL8TIFMKAgMqlWBelUgIwoQjAJAlUyOCSG8Khn0h7gZiAsoULIQJwtmqBcljz@IBxWvQJIKpKmqpRl5Qd7UHBQylyG6U/NQeQXwA2SpkFcVqEWF3KpF8Me4RUBcEcmy4CNCM4d9DXEBNYDEDKQGCMlBngg2hAezWshwkqLQLX1ktHnsFlFwHok8j6iEqGksInyziFHIThrAIIFDEVSo7Qy2BeFagGbJu9Awy/LZD7IQYEdMY9gDA/XOSC8WsNA4cLR5bjd2dRNIEJhQWwMz0jywC2Q9PhxjJCOjhn5Ot8@xJyb@MZeMSzym5WA3DAyvozsOw7DQW7tJ4kbuuOXqr8fYWc/y1QX2pgNn7mqGGWSA2p02oo4EvlEX0pvOZ7vr2ANqnAPkNqZtD5fwbeBtFwjokX2hz7I@Y33acGhChwDuOiBirJmQmQuNBAqSN8Kp8gxBJIzX7hsAkJICxmw4eptw7xUdYmeAhc9nsczU2r0MQnkQ6lcybGgDV3YxjjU2zTL0l3qbZWqpjn6eQhfe98z3OZgHvzeCDtUD0dJAGKDeGHMRQLqnytTPnfg169qD@aJx3rQfFL1vYB9iXmhTqL0usCV9og1AZGEoF1jQ8w@AYngNYk24vOfaZx3bio4CKBcO9M9Q6KAkANIknIyMgQ4CnQ1RsMazlGnkjJSz1hRImbCVlUme4zm5gShZuIko7pANOfDGAj1jZ9xGrGHahkUUBD2Ki8KNo2sd7iaMHHZ6qsHPga5v6ImyMhow4DFmLSRpQb@pA/Y9oaJNEFHW0S0X5CZXZgYKmED5PbsLxEadPQgtEHUGu01IQBQEThO5LQuEciSgwZnJDNYeDhm4g6QD5LmXLkJvbb8y2BvwNPsuM9tjx5myyRBqwhhAqFHb7naBet/owz6AYIMOa0/b0DyhkpF6hI5NnKg9nC/mzLauQxhLh2LvHH6N9XRAO/TtXcgpkfysAMMhFYFQoVm837c0wBQWoT2cEloATBCja9syunds3SViAbkoaPqYmKv3qGlAO@vOmNEA5RigUpAtLKBd4Dxe80L4mKCwsDCYlEcFn@gWNJ02UCU0eqg@rNNt1gUtItTlo5iotdv6cOTRiU3szLBCotHBHopG5Cp5wGS3L6zfB6lunmogaEA5ITlAOyMuiyoDSWwa8lpPVQHJwNIDYZhxzmJObyUPIc5vpC6@xDBzOXgpLsnDkJoEyonEJMYjZCXIHY12H3nhCLkNySrQ2pzx7eKDWzh5Z8CkbpA25kYBtiPIqcAJ87EchgQ/8zYgeWgirNqcAwadc7gDtOYOFkC2g0yanbCrnNJkYIp3AR3Ylr0AKiAzgItB5n2oLogYj5FraGZAjNRc3Lk6QoY906KxI4M@dDi0HWgZnOlMkaXxKgtRl801nljQV8RBA5/vWqHLiGKHPxpx7W1ogkZFTQxbKkilGnAKYGJclwCeZ/MUQxmmVk@wvPxdEOvnxAR9qWXpKNhqzpQDgeJB9wwJTZnhOMAGz7GT4H2Q35nIRKfQJ2idDnJWRAe1@5uJy0jRO@OWMbmpsLTRUX7lCueaw7qoqzggdEAjikW7bjReIXeKGfISU/ZwlKKo/C1CQAokQ5XHuqD@QCexB4zmeGq1Y@JcExOTTByPukUxDgaMyGU09hVtOLqZu1fghkQzOIN2TbYK60H3LUnwltCNcoIeKRk9NAfkDGiEIKuXSp2Wxq6AezhMmuxQbBQu6avI2SAt3eoEaXmIwLyEyyvzJFynTQYp1KthCTA4lZw6iTkEvicmKKIIDqmU17eiA0l73I/kGu44tmiggcW4KBJnl4GgDx1AjDJjgPBhtI1R0xNX7t3zBZe1ahWIDaQpYJudeFhF8EdkZODUEFgmacRLRB7ZxyNsG7E4lBcDX/PcgNgElFqtsctR34EWR/ZrAQIBWgULKdlHrFfPT42zcedmRVvoiIFEbHUgNBntkVgRoPPnraG6CqvROayCChFFrCLxYnwCfYt4yRUrVPSCObqL4m/Vy0qohmOYA49WF6KIR/XcZgS9M22bnkjATdDYOTdqQfbPPJ0/YERJTybwG@2tlsqBYHPgcNjh9smjqtcWuWeqZVjlOQfTbmsmOa9jcNGP@3j/wdH20deaC2CYRqt80yFlZIt57GrHE6lnjVNZWS2vh2HMAD9sroaNEefDiILnzSR7EhKVpm3oXCY@Og@OPr2JEpCEEB2UApjxd0Ok4WFA6BJamtu/0QmzXiIBSQZR/LBM2mc@zMCAWUd/zc/P4fjNG6y8m5kaeu6YM3OscQC@Y2rf8uPJ6HlDAPO9Wl3eI1JckEINC0dSZ6ZwSD8/n6DUfDMzJEqHSOaTg73doyqB7WvumW6aEgVJuSOQpTSnIwPNm@OOLiwKA@wPTG2WkGcZR3ma8roQwe32HIJndcuWwAcAqOvINpPMgV80tw9537lZNnKV2gEFkJ0g3JQrw/JQ@0MzGsoHdnFtVHkX9aLkMeusAqeFPVbgO99ttXM5vZAthbut9izNThjogIRiw/blRge8zlwJXeSZFOmJ1V72jx/fyrhLQiSoApKfM9dkMqXlmgJqL5LBom5qBzQ029Tl58TxRCbGU6moP4Qqt11SPkPhdyfGKJaO868Sh7CQ@vb2vvrQD@wN99FIBikNqItjz@R0ccqi7QKNWLZp92y2AXG4dOgnCGLT0mJu92zrVg1p6IhFjeAcCPBfHLjRhtDXGG9IcaRYYXWVz59olnsBXFrJZxBJhCEClaLw8ivtXAN0zcp9vP/FLnQiSi6dDsxpegAFoTiELjS1Q67kwCRISPbys7CAwXzIrdbue0ihCQkstMfogojbM@@FjsQx5dTC8Auz9BX7FsZf2dMbpAUunLTAEELZ/tPDx/tPd59sf346UnO5OXs2XcoD4iC9FshCcp/jDVvrBm@aWCwEF4G24WDzAi4wBgXFH1gfuw4wbhmDyDwDS6iGzyTFvmL3ragbv1mYC/SVXlltTkJPsPHxoF5EULQ7JiojDp@Aw/4c6ac/Gg3dcioFrbw/bsmgtKZetW1T66UoHnQMpplSUHXZP8BxDXdRDMiMO9V5DD64BaLDlEYQNXNgg/JCk3rIGliMg6dRK9Po9UEXxpk/3YnLAQVTaVId0BBAV04FZSMGTDbArff160nkpP2RohY5XStpNZsS/WBzzR/CrnV1UJ1i0FsBKuI3rOz03uk9NgUujZBuAokwecOb/MG@wGQgSNKoKer5PnKIW@B4KfIKwtHrMY7mApdK5dLZgpLPpUAtAzUNZFYJx9ykgTZq96WRLQE8ye7SuEGICrtuW7O68oZn8DMLct/HUNRM/cXpqdUAAf30HuUNp9Tq00ZdacQr7HaUDS98vALUO1c8pF3fAWiXjECa9GVL@FlHu83OOhq1rg5LjQZDr8@RhuzJNghSb2zg1x093PYwQirsmdqYC5vCwG9TCwaETIwq4AsxlYIGBT0tkF4K8yWB0IviIVAO8K1QBDYbzeDl4BPZIT6CSjfSvWFHXRrxR7kGR0vdISCRBpvbyKVdHB8cQe8YUD5yaahcZNLsQo/iOLrm8tFKiORNX/rxQVcLINCofDAibQXTtkAEFIvUc@AcQFc4bNqfjTKi0g@UBglSnnDwASQIi2YPesBnIDIvyDYvCE@JXOaLdGbZFxZCa@msKLWMER/st8cOTgsanXDZIHhG5WEAGhUuxNdp/rClt/koK49MpQAlUGMDfWDjUAJIV8QKdCqCxuceURd0ccQamlVawukXgC@x@zvAxdo6Hy@SBqhEAUntsujISW1LX6Q06Q1Q8wrZCgu/HZ4Kp0o/8RFAI5HBXDiNkngjoCSd2AMK9JzGW9DzgS/uCsPpqA8lBgoTtao91K2bOh/XCGPxCs3YRqPA8A0rdhldW1uLlqO1aBJMW2DaRNMWmhJg2iKTRCYMJ6OJYiTJhL51ioFujeh13Yc8iTeQBiYoObwxhjGtXi5nGkmtrnhfFb9xqArAPISW8ANwovFqFY3xuFi7wDkbkN9DZd9B2jluO8bQQ8FXQCDgdg8HGUICqPcozTt6BXXT1RgZVB1QGnUUMWNO9LSePm2cXp52EqfX0STGjle0KuiHwLxGsYHcc@zxEAS3erYsAW@L1zPlRqVVjaajG7FYUTIhIS0e/7gYT2gc17GoDjQVOz2NAko97NTbfYfgTZJqPB4gCvLRNUDLMM1YVL4sQvqteCOeiELceDQJbLkajQJe2ogElwqNIwKciPaMCaASGiZ0ceE5BWKQNDmFzfULfdifOuEAwagbSNk4gj6b1ofGQFw8zCXf8PhhgW5O0/flXh4OhFscvEN5aTjl3F3gOT1NzS0x8fvdc6k7sEda6jMZlCY51F1G16IpSYKekHw4JCr2E8PFJqxZuj12wyONCwdAMXVwPemPgVn662@SQFXGUNDbfZtF1@8DdBbM92BXglNXEp8A8wF02jL8kImiVIKTJSBd0MIUA/giLlrhozIKZYKzHn9sPpcfvpaD1CoUh6UxIaNn2Y4uAUoghkDLSGjRkVBj3tqUfRr5ujUv4flSl4aKt6EDR9wzbY1wy9l1aD5oOAjFB/0cohzpHcEE/tEF9ijzunD0TmpDoFla2@lDDwGlQU6sBrU18DxStjvsyKMJRBVi2OGGPbl2B0LnBeuoqppv57pl3w@pApDdh0pCrdQCFdf3khTwjHuVvMuHhXwd/enBw10@dkKdLXavOI7WHNidMciVnt50pFu9JNsFejIse2AAGvz4b87MI9secS0fLMtGZrjSbAzGpkZjPjeHZVbGa9st26ShoFVRZ@HHjquZGh@E8n23P3sCsv6zk@OqXA4FSmnng5Vp4zjk4mQ5PvfDc4403@pPD7mcMMX1nIj9lr@sDdmM55FHj7G3qA3qyHcvoLvfpHAOxXMvovsAF7SBrOyNIpA1cPQCliggLnLDtUGe46WSvkb3pTpYEE6hcFxwnOX2UlHJ/XzU7c45Z8j5TELWZM6cs@TMF7vN6YjhLOV4IFz5NhcmDChPYYIFcDfDecwrWGvQ101/BvEIBBOcJYO@3UTxCXQTlMT5KjQdBOkhToYQh8YpNtYGWdO9NWwBbWoo8dBCZI3aCfRhKZRchPUU84a4K9RSLNubmnQ597RBtafRk80an8xG1cnhWluKD76vNwHEZq3ir0laFgxTikaDYASV8gYxqJg0f3@rqMFqDJfG1AWKUhHcFGgNEzUtnU4Ku42US0joMvH0dPJxWv0clA9cPbZ@L9XTK5jcUmyRnY9Dt/vANlhiMo8yqIex1bXNjsQnvaD@GVeXsCK8NQfB@jVi@OBiOP7SNQNXs3hLDIFdhla93YJ7o@pqtwOE1skFgKA1XLKrs@T5FatDD3Yuu0PTGDXYtTyym30s/GjsWDdX1HGR0nG0qSt4S1aqbPvok8/q6QaHIAw0nMgq8tqa@AsyQQ4GuQfXvYIJF96MjBF17LSwwMDyKjJkakJzHpB9gMETqLAgIa9EmPUr/WpWlq4OimdMx5y700GS6fFruWtqo5Fucdris4nL0c2nfbxkqpT8ljeHUGZpmmgBQdNAP8hihR2fPNw9OpKBQt1YdBcnZMrQ7LR2H@SNZYX2MRkufJl93ImyjzFOHLVwAZoUKBNNLz4QbwWIG9QJSB1ZQU93YuAYx7mUNjjT9BVF5AKXhyBcPtUeEY4CYDE9DmUiYOWF@X9mcc3Jy2eZRVmCMAnojt0rA26NuDy2jNeyC/0GiaEQJMp1T1psW12PEftaV@JEP44xwLlgUJlICoQy1OtsDbgbhRZZ9S17UU9LpUZinTUaFT7DDxFRpqfFu95CUM3DJ58OIwbp5Xnf08q6N5YD@ynQyC3G4vlTgGYFj24hs864Nb3dSsV1VYwHmZXegAP3FG9mcsFyVZ5Ff40TsRBaEjW/tGl@4VSoWM9Iyb6xzByK42cgKA9OQ8Z4KdlalSnxuJ8zDui55qDqXGaHtusaLZPWwXZNgy8JCzrrsocYD5KPmXByFWwYhDdsz9DOsDJmi5/5kmIPE@RPHQ1oUlgycojF2SUik1CpIhbZ1RU6iGxdZUQGIq495vi99nVa4I@PbcjsY28tdVjmIKbhLU9B1nEqiL7yNj//iz5cMUid35B5pXMxHI/LnIZ1ZtMsUmBqpmUlh3JmEHtwZt6O2TXcPr3mggZ54GHVZblzB60uvRYEoMkUb5qeHGiY3pOwoTq11BF9aMR@QcrzS1Pmkm3p3bHVozlNNDPp9R0hpVKRAndbLWNZUEACrjbzvwuCAa/ElqfKWVnxWw8O8EC3CPyT60Szot9c1cTm8A6d1Ahied//@vUO4P927fShv8LxzMDQBEkBa0rqLq0sLypa6LW4Yvmw@9g0NEIMme4C2dYcKJJmBobFoGlqX5JA3hjgRIVX40Cb@AJZdAWZ8ZzzeUb/uziRRVN1FvDt9rKwN1Z58aRoUgnUxQ4hgctchk6RiMnyStAnfGInpLgjw707U/5SLEbEzOu9Px6N@RvE4Tsr0Rjib1Xb9EKmc1pL0UEh1VqGvqLKHe1s3LGl4VkvEIvzC8LOSk8zyxJIJd4kcxONi4vPC@gYPeju/e@yYLP@NXVBn7uowrXG7lBqkW7f4TZqCIMVKTgmfy8LYnh7ngLDcqwZJr3ekxI96EAo3hqLFK5glUJIM26g2dRaUxSF@h9OZcF6BeA41XYikc4smbAeDpfHR/2U4pdKi2NP5DbHx6KRhxRfJSvxsTkqsLdu9o5ahe7KGGimpHZCxqXMfNFyh1tBg5lSiqOf4zzR@cKam2EfO6T22NScmWkFic/y4U9OLBvn9rqNQ6NtgzgwZEpBVlS/6wh1GMQy/QV3s4RwkTK9QosqjEVo7IAWip24FJgWswC7PcKFqEto6j0YGl8AistsQ0Qi28sw1bYv8LdUfOiDJszfi3u0Nwtz9R7MSTLbpgb9@NLuYG7IEYc07yDUC8PV6bUYsWcLMzpqmwvd55uAP5gYHhy8i6xdw7RddkzvVQjqOYAF/l5M0GFcGpol0RB72LyCB/krJ2YVqpk928wXeykNXktrfex0ke973/flcAGHUpQ7OJQv/tiW4n2X8vWzlHN2VwXRFjIHV82GjCu62EVsypvRWV46UAxwOnBxyfbSRYopp/gA4pKEcSLnQpv6379D17EMtX7XMZySOA3SHUYoFcEwcriI/XdJLbs6tc77MaVbYAt3FSJUuWemDp0VvW9VKVPTygfGUNLp92dRXXOsj/WFisZB65WOu5FXKBnvn6m0V4x1b/wfpxxww0sQ6o2nGb5XrrGfRttKZqKByq7fLcrMM7UhSN9DVJ0PwXCIhtsxetZ4OFerc9qZdbQaZf2h36Ttzlzu0OdD@VDxDklpTj53dfqt1Ji4hofLzqrZdDrtCTCheZw5yypNKhPEfWXw91zC5DJLeRYW5@6ckHFxGoSW8MLGpSxIXabYU@BSKWUZlj6a4vs9uWnLts0PqSlgqh0DRTGQLGkB76oauyXueFtT2GzowsUBj1Z32aAF72083RLwg0rzqkoPTzS9V21KOJU6wGmueevq4ZvQtNVdqeCucBwT4kt6zeWypDcaoshFubCy1XEJ1W7ppsY/k3x2FbySnFkJb55peFPAOGXMJ4pnE/yRG0xpOAVkGR3QUvr6QCfrCilf67wau/5naaCJjb9l3hNdb6cmu3p7WYChAXzBwvfczHRIWBrZFuhXI1w9iHqKietTPddlHNifS1yI5P2B1tP5URerOOVswALX6HC1bmZcPHRR5uty2hBtNry8nCSgUZ3pU9f/LgT4ZNqGeh0P7h5uu9H42zgG@h6tfdnC2NtdrNW3@1Zf7/PV6IFtWeMAehzxo0lWZR1y3evjArnhcG7hfBifpm2a74NPZI2cUdp2d2GednFLLe4H@yC4U60FHt7nzsE7bcR5BxqWtpq@PoZ@ybVH9lCXyLYsqIkDPfy9jIf6U99/1xGklXo@YMT//l3h36lb9jR7NBzSpzk0xy69KKpEO6Hvkpu6fMELLbW0nZ78xh60ZM9R9lbD0Iz7YhbTMkbtPm5F55St9@xWu2/clemWro0s4yzlD/lw63vprogZg0kP0Vk2DUCvM5WRXqph/2P87C@rdG/0iHdrgWGFvLJohI42e0tD7azt8tFQNLEyDgiHWiPfEl6mTfXl12NjNAMaWiEVDO/yaQk0LMu7tyZjqWRFOy9mbNhbq7GUSklIR4Fc0tMg8CjLkp1fPRdqYpkMfy3LULiUlKPQapcPQbe3oohGB43QuC24z9HX3FKohZ2c1R/33NsMkw/Xd0BEw9fyYQtaIR0asoY@S7O8zzI0q2YKt07Ctwky11hfOaeSWzmpQuEUU9JsAz5N@EDVjZeOoZnG0OVvJnWXTsV5K6RAF785X8hxM12sTHsV09G7fAoETXeJiAObJmlBBpHaOKGPI@jIzLngxRmXZfeAqUsmmwX2wy4TWxYuPlpc/UGfKX3@VO9puIL7sTHCJaALqIJIdtGipTthf3WsucZXx1CyZcSG50DwaUgnfGAA2hbAe6L1jPajuYoIMukh2Fs/yj9z5I9Ot@viom@4uIAqMKwYmEKS40SMVNcEvWFByJvj9sERGLMGxDdXLgy9aGzdHk5xD9qUTKuG1Y0RjbJ632Wq47KlZSszcTEeDMeu91mcB1qiFR6FHpyRu3thAHDpNbBW1tfM0eKR6tCQK0hhXqc4My6Txr8wTLvHviimGQhtIIShcL6AcB5A93yI64IcawElUtrvOe2JAx2Swwv2GupWzzDJsIzR6tGc0QjXCPlfLAzvOXDfQ@oxvuX7HwpBOlmMkcd3y/qzDc939O9Aecf22GnraAxOMQmrBV6q@o6/phn3idh4CstFWEtr2yY0LzCYC5tM27bGI8kZWyt7hfzKXqHMJsV8iAxY7Ku7T57Fw9RAa8DvkkJ1UP7GrjmdmZYuGLhBZIYFgthyPjof2tclHvLTl45oAfIdcbbxiKg2seuH9iJ953Dq6KP3VpiA@Y8HD/U2ThvemfZT@4lt2dAbDYFRDo50fpLA3EKPxREx2mPcKw/46dyZzDGBXdIJcWlDG@otqF9zZnqfvogDfqiNtCVdEY0Nkv4XmO6kFcNs6c4rGvQLmZeptPMZeqRPSLdYTjC8DUqjdpuLxDgeN9dG5mZs3KFtW/xN3DYNH@XJaq4CXQG93n@iXMbl/XPjAgv1s/miHpzzVSJ6hx91saysjt6yTf5esSbJMviaAM0xdDf1GE9OILd8lkkgfbkreUhhJQ@ZqUYgyZ5rLk3SL1Y1ZiCVyQcsAeprTtvGmTDPsGJ1Tui4gzvYdLBjgC8caAHiJ8CxtPbYO77xrmyZg9aAXksVhlBtHukt3GvUojNCRtrkdmXykSHvgITQiq7gWAGfXWGjzrPYIWgj8bu7rTk9ah6rxpBexKmXTpfTYh3JMvT2Gw1HzWzC12xses4fypx6SsYlY9WhZkSjyCmN9s8vbEnzS9dAoDF1adR3QOdPjVYNb/uHtyyYDxkPdJxknp@FWSq62m6fCmsvnk8PmKujS94JgsBLgtMEuXwobS@VPBE8/B88@EoKOuFmPusfaAKs6@4ZfMj82LG8z/tQ4KHtjrrG5ADyjZsOlrETLFYOosCHtww0bSwrBNSeNTb56EMvtO5q0CF1TKJjcCXJJHY90iXdOpfoeLnJ7RLZfCtZahvPUx3pHck7XQFnGqTH/q6yIJj3XTCBGuaNuNhTSXHETvJZb/nnIuRe@JwB5C17JA1d@qaG7uH@44MTeegqC/un7T5uxrglx80d16AW06EhqVeaE5rv5MvROoY7Sj04VqSdx/syBliCbz6jIcEHZ@bmPkvHPb3TS7WUtlQLQl99tFhAfHTy5HFitvGTxXb6jj3Q42HvnePjJG5s@crxQu9w7D1oHV17sjT6/q6ixBeQ7zOLZgeXcc8FKS2DdKKDNgrE@Iif9nKncNW2h3rnZDrUP4POEzm4@57J55cW8ql2bvSwFbLSUkRRQ2UlOZ@Nh1Zmg7KtO8F3WX2eGUPklm36pPhn6XIUlBwyKSezWHpYNeN/U4phaW8lwodFUtK3qXVkSNAyen00pTT375sxRVGW4flY60K9stzSypoPsGh@2LTP32MqWfeUFylwkkZAVZJx5zrygjQA1p3CFw7Pe45gbC1dBrMKQOCcX9jgL3RrqlkSzWWtEi/KEBsXta0M8oX@HhNSwQqfczxTeuEcX7CknsXaZIzfkfCJE4qys/Ng/64IRx4uV4f65Okzdqi5eLTJ6oDhHOvvkeOZZPRKwnErPFdv6XRqxwFQ6kp4veHi9lxmx5rTsa3p5O5JONrZil07HVkcwEIbBdJNY2Is6qvafFzrcPEyo7vS5ps47OmcHBw@8sYD9O5b/0JR0mk60Ai/Sppb76gZv4GzGJq0KZ6SF/Y62Q9YQxvlFhkc4gu10cf6BJej8NHgRUr9wv4tv6LvK8SXdyer/Ior/LIr0rvlh44sI6eVFQBzK/xYTg68H9vmRd@WdzRHdxesP16YoVUFKa0oSCnEnd8U0zgIShOLnnm5iI9bF7zPQmo90UdOdti3W0Z2YRm2u3h0JXuCR7Df9veWU2gOLW/p2d6WD25fnN7FWF@Y0BPtzWIP4jRnC72ACer9MW2JuO09P0HaAplXt3oGP7WRPbBHu2RbmMlDG1esL0zyoTF8OB4uzyiwRLww4CYXnwv4HFRl@8JlD2gLHU5Hz0T0W9nhO@COxlb4TGY36Z2qwTeu8q2EruwfnB2LWYlEPD5/w0N44yTfMogn9/HdfhD26oqteZv6wCPY5@htJcQDvkDJ0HEDrkAgcIdnzKpWlVyJbeE9C2UQIeKUIjrRMUp@WnW2funt0CuXlWvcpSiWRebtoAxOReUnewJcPJMQysSkM4Wtj8Bn3d/fx@iQenbFSC0BOUjJpcEmp8IbrivexkfI0vrl4f7h7vHJ9smz43q6cS3Gve29PG@WBan5G78/znREKLuHNmB3/Jxf2iBsQnJ0gD6qM65fLgYlu1G06lzRZoUStzDO@qVlpVK0zzUlXUP@JJGnRr4gu6ATh@2XmOrH26Zc5ttDTUKpuM5Bi5Qm1FmZpRclPNSg6a5bnv/N@z/Il2Uy6MsT9o5mBcLt2XbHS9HV2d2Pn@Le9v7jZ0e7zM/gjGgujM6oXy3l@Mm9KBJIOtRT16BVM1UW9aJEoa6q1eheFBATlaOsTLuL6dRcoHMI5mMH9yV7sTdYbJ3gAwajQaWk/uvXU9dRGReAxiFs1M9UlHmYxwDsBHcM/umPOvxUef@cEP@iG2dA/R@dxyB4u4GX7AVGjFLDHC6/7oZOcadtv8Hx8bMrhAS6XQCo8oKO@Lpx/FOcTmThdxd5p3P5CRGB@CdR40ginrTluOzcwD2/PA9dPPhqnpRx8QEd9iazbbzLB2ieaXTFAWR9bI344TLeURQRoCM5YChJtk6Z5RciiKGA0c01IOWWDgyWuRaoZ/qozF4BneFoXZlvPJekWvRWFB80v8RJ6o8GZijgrZOy3NSpk3r3a/8s1aswMI/A/G3PPEk/ANuveLYumH@Vm1@ksN5vn6w1y0s4Q3ganlcCnpEA/4j70BVGFt/sP0McHgDmc01mDKCazgnrGJynwN8SMNsZnFj9M6g0IDeoMW@TP09PdxoxPI6vnEohSWGnL9PaZn3CFxrdOJYvn8tnlRRkUjr3AdI52j3cQckBxuNlaATCuTGsvmwBqW1uMhElf72ar/CaTa1bLzLiyyCj6xBWuOhj5uoM4kCUWQzwq3nRoGtJKHGMirwpqkSRLXVs6HPIH/smtFseIkQWA2RxHOl4MPME77IaOVP/eMkW3g8VumNh3QMkKdDjkCkuCt6@9Kf2CMhnbkc@35eOC@14/4bntrn8rjY61RHpUb7dsmbbKf3LHLy2JiMP4KAy6ZtdZbhuxecI4hhBlMVF5Ft/wU5Hp1YjxWmTAZn@YAExW2D@5VRvCc3ycm/fPtMvdvNEPkQWu39s2aji7EFhWExNqZmUko/PipTNLiySVyIvGSgOnjRyBckBmwKW0daNV/bQ3d7Z3f/KweHxrXPrKGT0ZjDg6rXNxKkkJ@uNwBANF2u@Sh7spY6fPNjzK2KW6XyIG4Mk45VEWVWS2cgFgpythL9ZtEU5vFm65Tl@zvfK3sxvRl2VNYp0Kx9K@gPSpdWo0h7tKbmZuFpchK1cblWWZvBSIdA7fEPgrazG4pfX9cZm7dSKRG9TwoKG8CIib2AjANOpu7GeQmK/XTgsWHCn4gle5uSG22JmcVsU1zN4fBLuRx7ZZ7ODozyHkEeovH4ywCIFOeUHXdr6DrgEPjveTOV3PvKDlsLHy4QynE@vwngI1Il/fSRykdnhjN65hH3N7ZtGS/CP9eHnE/rHqAVHE/IjeWJxwTvinycc8y6UnJQnMi09icWR2xGsJFt11KEPLy5Ag0bZ7XAM@suhPeRHPtMU40PdNx3ZwH5Bc6K1Cjr7yngA4br0OdJpuBc4twSRAZPRIKtclgIu4Z10OEngWZKQXh3PO/QKLg86udgkLvf1ScfoAW@PxZPA0T5WlAYLTkPEQtPph1ZUpDqb1cLKpvgJbvMMo/2DjsSczDKg1TUZ9D59EoteROPlBqSP7tGL5@fRuLiIluhoTu@sys7NMzqD7BeU1ZxEG3mt0z8AcxG3KJVucwlwuwmYHy7l3zdTKsl9V6D7w6oolx@PnMdgBDEi1h1oQxYbW/wALpmRNXYas5J0YpFU42f4WSyRIHUJPuQhM4rZJRPvv2OaNWWxVBWIAF1dq4OfN8aQ1RVZboCZEomzdbwHagckLjzMJi6AhgtRygS2iiQESgTkiDcSmRM4xEF/Ac8YcugYswXedC0OjYrZiBMqNavdY6F7veYlR7FUKnsVOs8VSwyo7zY7lFMA9haf8@V6wK53WAbgDJRbWYjMGPltjhehdCM8I4@8UzYgO5HQuZv@4RsMYM1OxWz3HfzFdi1oK3heUPnZyV6zGE@JLDito@cYHRy15UdHBwqcd9kHNNPUXNBohetrn2A0PIatyY8DwVPC9qjBiDdYaiSMhpvX5M5oU1FWUr0X0asFCJnFDsDb1dT0weF5g/78@QK/xcz@5z/Hi3jF2LqinDWd80Q0l67AS6nkWI59vH4qSev1dPX@ugZa1Oj15FRkWiq78fBc73db@73UqSiyDMumUhvRvY1DQ82/eD25zijF12dDJV@XX08aYrGaPGtM2OHh52@bb@Pi5HwqnsZIs2Q7B1eikkXFNVIuscutfCZyVkIP/3nDP@qy56bGLkZFFjk9xQt2xYKYStWjDfgnr5fw8ED1mlyTtxpv38brTNNGkyk7jeCllezgPvmTooSjTqoaPzYMI8VOh26nAz@7zxr85uUIfxKJmMQ8B6nO3SqDSZfcJtt6rzfe1abc3YiM8bM38uI@@eL58@doeE4Pe3MU8WBT7HtlL1y5qeUiTE2rf/rjtevk5WFz80@/MUjpa/g5wM@3r5@g@VjJfby29vGDB9lsElDDzYdfHH5te3s7@zCZO6zntrJSem3zpz9ZW1PVTTW11nBdpRGtn519LqrprCj/6Q@jzcPDr7puLfN/fP1tTcFXAV7nrAB8Ap4MU8CI7yL8FJSxztgbeM66DP/J/KYTMmtobnXfsMibCFC5EpnSX3NWyWtMqW0V/tt3D15HRpGamnruwHcUeR3JFyPcCAawZXzbeaQW2cRg@evINFWtVsFY@G//HuLXvgJw0Ge6Ca9azoeVn0ZqUpWiXEVqeTAoqgrp/l9f/3qIeDibqJIY5z/3WR0eMVtQxa0GPBv0bAp4RpqUTqV4KOtez4beTGdK8Z5yD@yj/ki38WPwj6XjYdVSBbTuo3oikWjITQke@QXp7oqingIDYHOkRS2EsORZuQsLu3kePDAnnecRoikgKqIrbvYciNS4w/Ob4Z4veCrP/7GfIyGSX7uvP6zVgBVmapmNWoKetdNymaM/xQpF0bbvA5NIsuipGGUv2WOvcmpiuqiKyWTyfhOtE0SpNInMEMg4jlhkDrMRNrOxsFOE@dHYLMyHhtvF58/@1z/73p99l/6@R7//hMfJWR2jm9qAeOfQdGr8ga9Yc8TLU7JAgdPlYrmYal6fxjaAUzWOmJL@5Cqay0SP@U28acZO4/5oZyR4ajV80b9nIxN9b7h5PrXAQiFmUVaH85EagS7YW3gn1c9rDQkFp6pUV/K5hsTp0S9jrcTq96GaRLVQEhs1NaceQNUpIq@4/rrL7AhokHmItAXPGvzRPzyBdQ1HlNfIbc33oVC3n7Ug3TsfgFlWNtRMKvdxflcVIvV6qqE3QJBlNR/I/bXyWrGcL6up5gq4rHLbSdf1QzdyrijtVqv1pt3S4GlpbU0ZafflglyU1c2xNtGm2qg1bk1ao/a4rShC5G19jR3xZtBgCf85Tdz5PJPlpmckg40/SbInESHyj/DUFFVhG8BI0/AC6YGMoNzhH5SDRS7habzdqL/dAAqpJTapeTZqkpdL@MjN@42EdH1dB3Ol4v1v1gJjhR5ugsI1rhOJzRc1Saq/qNUTAPKFB1LmMOVmrbFJHkFaXmKedzRrR/P2/c0Gg2QTm/XNqr1DP4gJj9QAuJtzeb1/PyGD6T4AqK2DIBFPJNYlaQ15eN3jVRC4UUv4hcI8gHSzuQkEcL15Xbuub15fb27C/ya9r70vuF5v3vqnz@xZEmbm32D1jFqEfNVqp/VU7TR16hFfA@xyqoYucuoUDDX4QjjozIQINE@9LEQ22EYEj5vKRDaEyMt3X/7P@Dt99@UfYE/P4E@IpDZQQShxPQFejD2x2BP@WBb8w8@3ogs6PKmho8VfFs4hpFIvZVbmw7QxpZiPy8gLm3a3iXOFMnsJQRkyCCaqxbzYTChTlUU2xXyBWMQv3nqi0eg/eamWClGuT@N@y5eu6z4J5QzTZk8Y/ugPolTUtCIpVzV@vjE/Wf4XFz3/5BeXPULkqgS4Y8D7XMZxIkSgIiKSVBMitc0BrsrDYW0JNYjz6ufSs20JVV5tRJMWba7OVfd3q6VSjY/Irx8S5Ww83IC3Av@7a1AWATsYIXKJr9Zr/Hv8Bv/YSRv/jl7jHzt5g39HI/xjT1r4d/Ia/7Zb@HcywL8Hr/HvyQj/nvXw7/QXMhmlIq5fEioSSkm5Xhc30oSTSmSrdvoLvK660Z995xvfiFarUSlKp9tnFVD/lXgFsOm60cr9qBCpsnVlXUmb6XZaaSktMBgs7bB0P91XOiAjNhWW1ll6mp6y9MBWOmDS4S8NJiPdZekeS1tpCwKCL5hGzfQITV349OCvC4Ac@DNw0UhLSbcZJGSiJEnXYiF4MF01T4U6qMTiSx3EfFmR03LeaOBlAnWxoZaKTEYakZv1l6fRBp5Sq5ayrDXV105fsogLKkIlkjo9TfHBDigmYeL6utncffqw2Uwh/zx9Yh/M/g8OBmHryv/Bgf3kwB7Y8H9wcPAEGl8tcT8BrOX@/SqwGu@zFalVtk7LxLB8phVJbW6d1jISmvMJ4EMquiU@8JlBhG9t7VSIXsRQurtAAa/y/KJyXiHzhW8FQ7MyC@AH4wbvC88F8GZfkLuA5/wCDWRD48Xz08DEDannF6eo6YAKG/yDCB22/gP8G//v@n/yjMVZrN6Ixy6vN2P0xPEvHr@8vrz23rV4LOZZYpvwhw5gxyiX1zU0UqBLMNVj8Ub8@pq7wTsW3@QAa5DMZo3izsIB/4gESVKy/BX7h/1C0t5zGq0wbbYI4fR0kk7HKy3/@GycdNOuaC44XqHLkNZbdaXx0x/SIelbcQqUy1YqygbjFjWrVipZ31YoVipF37Iei5VuP7X0lpIHeS2bjccrFbBs@WDTYA3AFgGsb8kBVN3V2h4DvNw/oOPDgUvkIng@P2cLsTRdMoD31UTFsnjvXsy7B3drO37vnlpKX10FLsMhOClzTs1mx3CaTXTPXF2JTZHWBJRyYE8Xr66UdCmhROO2E3uKFx1BUjFJYR@rNUq1BHxXzRbi7B/kAWC5zc18tlbLZ8GcL@L85e2HsMHE9Wjk0u@7C3HOGqPrKbHCVVFo3S4@7PI6QtXOsrl4DJhrHOS/6wj@cWelVOLucZbNx4qJkvdXXYuzGggj/A/17Uwiu1HYuA9iGv5NFj7IkyuXelW5rl7qZRy3vK60vWsmcb@sfu9epgRoLaYrp0Kz@XD7ZLvZrIqiiD0qvNCRuLuAt1sNnWidqjxXatSxhI3TaLRcuU/koRRzDOjACydFoZtgxRIhQjC6uBkeSi8o3mjGmqDSF19CyRvjAMcIdun814GHdViL9fBhPWYYBjOYSQ8zGfend7sdBLL54/kGVoqLT@CiB48QOXy8vbN7klQ3JRZR97Z3kurxswcRBa25mZ28M2g/2t1@ePAMIhw@3t0@3v1k/7PdZ4fg7rKL2ePzee89@4ZNC@wX7Lnwynmj6bqmj3W9eTEeX7xmrwyjaUD9mWMohN1zmKs3Ie9DbVaOCvzahqu9eqU5Q3rYux98690P/rt3v/udd7/7rXe/@72fffm9b8HvR/D7Dv9@59@Vcvj@2Zf/4vfe/c7vguN/gt8fw@/HP/vyN7/Of2T/E/j9l5Dbn3i/UDj@EwDWr/zsy@/@8Gdf/ur34fevvN/3b/9@7ceLf9/75vIfxvvu760O851/D7/f57D8sN/5He6G31vhf4eH@9Xvv/uN/8D/f@r9ofF33/3Gn@DLs/zz7//0v7z7xn9U1eJP/@27b3733Te/8e6b3373zX@qvvvNf6ukw6/fe/e9P/zLP/r9v/yj/5H@f0Tv33@f/3ff/@d//r/8@f/253/k/X4Mv/8Aph//@X@EtvE3f/gD/P/uH/7NH/8A//@nf/03f/jrf/Mr/4YMv8UN//e/@nf8/Ve/9p//@re//Zc//vpf//qP//q3/vAv//df/T9/8z//1X//B3/1z76Bjr/147/841/5i2986y@@@S//4htfLnl/a@X7y/dw//IfweX98/k@cN6nXB/q8uXfKT9/H2zMUgE6Aer@5Xe/@UtA4L/B2Ltv/QgXl8Nvyf@PVIXC/Ijb/j9gUG@XGX3SYILfr7/71ncQRf8DoAj@A3x9O7DM@XDLt2cWQOtvL4j0yz/78l/@kGwRvVyjoXDsrotqMbEBKs1GqeR12d4oOUT5pXloAQAvpW8jh5rz@zbytnc/@Pq7H/7Tdz/4rXc/@BXsMKVsKbmdlJTVYg30sFLuPcJhwPz7hMOAn2P6CRoPkhKfg4197nl@/vnnQvMqhbsY7l@B6@fkxB/GvXCXg@fl@6E7bntgVyxs9oxpz7juuQYpUy4w1QQJGhu@FJTLsEnCy9AEBy7xC@4QaLJBxgm@yRW9JwK@Zv8z40RgCQzDH7z0yTeSwYvnJcGNQg6SSUwmPrpILGNcFNrgLjTpRulmSwxLMJkkJqDvggFSSIDXgwSrVqsJjFjl@QErz1qtyCgriUQVyo2xeZxks4ggJg8ICsSsJo5Yc6M64RETCK/moyMhoNORqKhiolh9CAlWJw8ZwkLgBPbly2qtWJ3UENxbjo/EJPGA8oTAqolJ7S3YqwQT4gmRh28hK8VqIlErYoJYSF49ySavpBwVjsqeYAmvDuCL49hb9xn7WFSKYpNLh4gwHhrfiVnoLZqR3AL/08SGVxz694302yCEr1FSXiqM@2@RILrFZVMMAHAlSZZlBj@c5dxi98F7wkElKFn4JDiEBFEEUUDgwHDEJyEkqH4TZIH0I9WND34QGBZmfX1diNTEjHggE@pSKeaclfmlPVdc9SozMV8S0VmnNfN@XiB@hdJfj@LsQ5RxwOzjBP/dv7/BPoZi0nfmJjApkbGzdoRD2UwkRBXg1@yE8AI0EAHolABdCfKkSkpOQkgmGZOrEfRjBwcHXibI4UVVSACZqxkF7ThBMh6PIxBDlpNyMul9ZfqSg@wZZPL1vvI6IpcuCmWqmq2AolRh6MTCWo0CCjA6vn37FmqFFquU90E3Zd66FTVbJE9w4Ju4TXPq761QsyWB6@VMyWcZi9EQKDxxFhdYjG3EBb7EmWfCf2JRtViMUjjAvhzb8Jcx5RUiBxz@jNQwo/7DlcViLu577hywnYMnT3afngwbDSbodPGp3hw6dlt33Rj6bT99yHc5qKV8PFKvI@iTsooMRtgtp4n97T882j8uM15orwpilLEKTT55xSwpQmQ4fL4Z8ZZxiHjLji0e47s8K1tMLWUgaqQmRNo6ahRAS/gPv4rwxO09sCeg8idFMankUY2L06AvE75mjxmeAcc3jEObwkXv8uYmYUCoXUo0NI9GqK28UKt5C6CYItSOd08gwskBU9S0LNQ@ZxMZE5SuhZpZNXWrN@qv40oi8TQthsq0Xk8n8U/NZOCtZPNJJVdorK2ZlxKmeUrVdolLwq7BeilhMT6ChwkfCewjcIIH0sB1XsxbZLd/UPFWOuFpKzG@3ElUctDM4sIpVDQHJwzDT2UI5A1afegnRNa@@GLEajXQpaX9PSEC7KLP/NU@ktGR@zLVc2fs6OTbY6xjfGbg/Ulyx3CHpjaFtgPoiFxfX3cB0v4eU2sqWXmMDr6v2@TSAvP1RBMiVrlcfatkC0JWLZffZlRVAAch8uKFptVq9XTjMltQs7lsTs3k87mCCkgrZfO5YiatpPPpnKoqpWy2VCwVrlkMalbTpFo1o2aEsreGO5NJC6Tg///P3Q9Nf2wOa4DczdQQjBoYs5spDYwtMOY2Uy0wGmAsbaYMMI5rGSW9mRrXBCZs8uPPGO6uroojfYKnLXI3sebqZlfGfRNVkRJQxU3vONGaF6@GG1BsrVPFLbi4WSAWvxQ61Y7dpnvghI7csjtT2R1NTdxUYNpONQqCVtT3MPBqXdyiWK2zhjy0h9AhqrlCoq6kgS3jTykm1WRHbpu65mzlyrkiWoJJna1cunxBO@Dkz588fjQaDY902rewlS2VOzKecYKnEWwVy7lco14XxUSdkmngtZK8zUtra9BOdK0jwbdrWyNXUosNiNwxnGo1Gt3KKKqklDPponAdFF8AxGGZagLGTGBZkoi8S69RlS3bggZcTmpJ45LKXe52u9cbl4mZRdAuJW4DjFxLWrJ1GVgrUihcmY2TkjHzBBetC/3LpTejVRbVXFGs1CszeyEvVhrXwv2B3jE03K1wmr68HSsPjI5DjUBCp0y4Lju2PSq39K7t6LOAGSXvB@QZuh0gK14HyZ2mMcXL28nlMRDgkGMOKJUfNlejFXp1YAqNXWj19camfwwdUqiqSmpGyiiSksH/Owwq/r9/eBX@VXxDrIwqnOBW7KfAoqFbsdhj3NI5stmJbdPthg/09pIQO32NliLuOLbr/j3CPNCsM@710ODnnwVejzS82cQdGKP@khDPhgPcxa07/2gQdgctyCA1bArwAF6OaduLAhTYs8MlpXwSnDgKyOBHjkLwo/1PHp2Evie72zuPhDx7cPD04Y1PzguUY493904Ca4H7@lFzAYiv7T5@fNPqfbIHz466Y9vBn7B38Cw7ewVOuNNNyMIzHyhwJiDeC60kxOCA9RrLFXyDIuD66HugiN3zjLn8zJhG43O@jc9wg/W6fL9mWTjx9/ZpDBlQS2dtvlkfNUM6SMeTG5VCSRCGzLIvWCHNOrZpanhbbHcNHPsa7lPSUXgy6VJjTPrCdszOhdHR14QnuCWqpOCVmJgJ4REAGYzbdGoF9MV4LFsH73HFGZKWOdbZGO9KXuIIH3RCo2P0@tDBXNh@AKGlaYxW5HzYA/H18DNa7TDiaZDbLR/zdnAhImgjLVKs3LunHDpuLV0u9/Ta7gSIlD2DRqM502QxJ8ptcY/JzUjPqLuNIdRTJptX1k7TZ@WsPaxpDp4f9nqcyNZBRhx12xXo2HJlQG2tuJXdSeccsZQR/@q3f/S3P/l1YG4bKXhFFFHEhdhriiCTEK2WirliKaMWk8VSMZtT8rlcUlGToH8USiCCppWiki/mSkqymC1lgOJK4JsrFYQIX@WW2iCQ8C0DWKuNlzRukhwu90Hg5nNi7E1Mi7OIFtjHTNQhjiigyjOiXZ8bRhW6Flz2likwgKixNovs7e2k9/ZE8QFacBnATloUO2jJFdPpwgNR1Mlnp4gCg2jzOEU87kYccUs6/WBHFMccAJ4UK4p9tOzmcdBGFA207Gzv7WE6XbSoGB@CnXEfbjF9SwGCWWgBwZEAvA6gQbBtnk6WMrqLFkwSffa4zw74ieInfnbQ54gH4wAe@SXd3hbFfW7Z3kafHSp2jmf0U7Rs0yOKDliA@EWxB4aeA81OFFtgxCYgim0wtacauOGFmHiYqDXSRHHK0YMIEsUJhdbaZ6LY9N0xmc@83OQQu2WyKLzU98lSwj9RVP1MY7BMYMmIYjawZKFsjx59pvWBZHv8mTr824aSPnqU0YzJeHev9cknrV6v5Uy3dz85Qq@dnUfQu0/HTqvX8iK2mvDYEGvnkaqdDaY3Hyj1frNZ1syFXp82m1nNuuHVnDZ1zCHEeg05854eJjRo7oDXzqPmfW3R/CQBbGLrH8C3hc@DAXwfaC3u5T/kRd9JqyVWkPxREqbbsqEl0sXVyYHWduwK2ifVNcaisWhyWs@nGxXyYAOQedOVa7omO4ZvDQcZ4pfT@qSablQn1YLK17Z0Y@LpRM0ZYnJtsKWUcuU1bUtRs4lJGXeU290oi0rKFosp9zbesNjT@JaayZbF060tSawrjS1VKZbzhRcbY1GMl/G9lSmUIWA6Cho6vuL1QmOrkAtFKRQSWkotFwrxyjXgYwTdeQuV/2YsdqFrZ/E4ZhdVUSgCv6R7SuU0Kt3YJDmp8nyxabwyqSoVfn4eS9@C1cHDWsftke1wiD0AN9lKl@kacFEpFUVIP5WKxePA74g1wXe2ku75V0/OTk4@B04IerunIh/yu2UrnvWTRzsyaM2eDQ9ZlfdQ47AdeQfZ1ZwPPwPUdzoBsVx@BP0nKCW@G@7scWxT3p209SGqLb6Hf3Se7B14Jp88moNz3AdNY8/TddwKnZpjtXWGZ9AaHaZVa2DSOixGuWJa/IJ67matVm1WB/wm71oQ61NGB7TOwOy7PO/Bdm2Kfom7XTyPZjV9XWlVJ5EJwGlWmaS8HNidl2qiXeng0bMPqg8wcqUJ31ZFr@p4n7kYESvdLavK2Nhyta5@qDt4EMH@wTrIEbgFJtZlenydndLt5zsovF9LNYdZs5w9HQ9ioKa34vNOISuiJvZVv8iXtCcL5/yvK90qi72IV16D1VlnsY78IL6VrXRiD1gzDi7pl92XXaayfLZCd0LGEBI0IsIN3Soer9Y@BdGHAz4rlyEjXh2fAUxMCcAaHfLQ4kPjutKumiwmsQmLE3qylV61jrGv8LUpiWJDkupXDaEmSc@FGrTTyjSiVd1xi84rZ@mWoqbzlQm4KYVspQ8Vq72YVJzqcOzoFROs3ngR33qmVQCdgDUA8@Yq9u6Xvh7flHJV7lYhUFcmSBtNuVmdVCw8AQlIopqpgkeink0nQamFVyEJ3byaTyr5ZCaZTUoFdIU@PplLgiMoNiBQxMyYyJiYTE/SspJUdCUZS780Oi/jybMYyCuEMhZPjuxdvEwdXKCSkCrJCl@NxRPqhsmgFmymbUpEpsApKlgwwHmfDY1kH0Ed6ZpJMeJxiWU2YuZ6DMOsn4yHu/VGubw7GX4VvGLS6618opBOvInHK7G1eNXVXwu1ilBDrkKlHq4BzXpDacwdD@pQx2BSCmq5Xm9hEQvpZCadgdIZzaveplgTG8n0Wl6BKrpmJB4xzjG4iDQTcmZuTZS3TR1qTimpFUGmwSNKUompJTUu4ApEL6Yw9NgaYpLFTkV/m2UsGi2o0Wg8WsGB7jXRG9kEXkZ8LApMNXpP2RJB/hLLYknFADOWSDvp0mER7FrAwQCWLQmRS@H68noTtNkUrQcE6ZGtkUmSa/eFSJkxkANPvXNbUmuMfegyw8Rm7QX/nuLKaIAr0FmFIHzS8h/dQBWMfYa7hrdYFDKmOYO6qmYadbUAPRlwRz@oqioVHNyP4NpruQYodi8hf5uJGm64@ZRNp1pC8keb7zHWS6wLVOjIzQm87ep272jbX9y0vYPjl6eCKIqVqBi5jEai1/AnRO7TLh@V7/JhkdA@Hz6A/QvR@5FoNIojxYCotxFiEmzn0h9yKuPVOTGtzFlCvRF/@9QwL4sZiY8rAI@6vo6sp6hqvF0TlU9fqjmoLMv2t1GALoTjN9Bb5XI4ChtJvRy6X6jFzJP9A@uhs6czvomimG2KtQhLKxJuSqiUPdec2Fw7U4AoMmLmLBlh9yO0kFosFVVR5Q6VCDuTokqZb7wYHpdeFF4UXzx5dvDsYE@InK5drdk44M6CxWBvra98FQJGM9koY6fVyKSarXhLwWo1SdlU8aikAisDv@8qeSl9VeN0XSOPvAo@737p@9nJZhHsaloBu6rmEmqtpmyoLB4ZvvvyD/BcjMvdz7Yfs6irTdnf/uSHauFvf/KvaXlV9Lri0vBwIQIh0ajkC5HLy@Hl5TU83C8XaUR4prKFOJj5NIISqaUUNWNZVoWVU5q2UUhk1ftWJeWFVQpKPOJKEW9CpJCLuFeel5ougpc/Y0FOYh6rJLJ7ZORU5f4mUosS7Aljwd@m7pYiQqT45OUVY2Bp1zq9nqGSKZVi5bcS23wrbbK3OEnwVlpjL6s1nGRWcCeZP4a@gTtmcCIpWkukNqIM1B9Wq19XGglGo/CgKL7Q9Q3r9Aatn66xUumG04YFf/qGS38YyXdwwerb9I1XrhjbiKdSnY53otKmznI1IIWNFOTsNP7ul35TVfN/@5Nfu2peNT9XQTsslfKKGvm58vOfQ4AVpxn4qh1NNuCxA2gIVEK25I51UHCFyNhCGZiH9xVEVAlRgjB6Fqj1aBPOUeqhWmry47I6MQq2gZudkyRD0wE28YogBLImychOr50kGGwDr8CAZitcCh@hF3StrAosVfhoBgocBtCZ2u2ma46dIe1diFE8pZFk9yAKpPARnkS2Rpu0Pb4sAStLbdyOyrPsEtZIQmID3XXxXDPoUoSPIIp3XCHe7K3heQIY0rCgI5AxCOWTPDp1SLsBaZs8QpNcY1R6HiDJeO54JAvkaOEjEA0ICwZIDMzYhAAV4DkfAQKgDDEPsNFgmywTZ5dGIlGZHZp2jcu28Rg4zd/LLGA0hNbBvfN@5AqGAyeQ3/GCLKQLr4ZBWAs5@kA4DD71WwUNAKOTDUUwOmzgvUEBLDrYJ0ZFY/fuzXJVrRqdOKMSIfwzY4iDV1QP1uK8AjBfe/q4UxaTDI@jq/iuAdkBxhOUXaA6iZ9DVwlFZSJarwUB/t@baJEib1QVeVSwAF598VbRBpRBZEQ7r8M226wyRS3EWZD5NuS9TZmiI9AClfB08rGsfu57XkMOfx7xj58HRnQSHhD06PbmZnYGPeIYz/7GI404M/A2ofNDi5Ch7Y/82EEsKIphUuiu4YC6QnPS/mlosYwSx2iz0@MoH7QYW83iMmY1F8cPxcLQDL4anvvlpbNG55W0bahQd2hbdFAYHWSC682BIoBHeWcs8WyPrQu8K8KrG4oczpFL5ysh5WOO6eAzumST4uKkcMsBndbHTZLpPZm1Bx2mlliMCI3OgrICcHGKRBlugeyLOG6Z@gCydKzrtJHILadSPZCcxi06EOuJAXTV3zOgV7HclHefaerCODNSJ3jWtWR3cb8RP14ggsIWNj8@/@wdPmXa9hkzjTOdj/PG5g5ncBlI/yDBJgGzsx8gtowLG9RMkqXBO8lDwa8AnwI3FpOhuGuxafz2N6OsxZpYo1fUyRgO3lV6rlkh/NJzJXgKrzt1/eNd6JASsMsBy9W9gx2qUdyyHZxYIngH1VTpjBQZ5w@GMVA//QNe0AiCuX7OUHUVsI8Bptn2j0rAVgyl/Yg6AGp70LLw3LeRU8YDPiAnTifWhqbnMXiLfcwyqoAB@ek73kk5AAOrvjoPHfwgKpbDHXWgYmQaNEe@Aq1z0AE/3FrukR/G96kbzXQm34y82ZoHDjsdSqvKeLPwLbmQBVsH0jMVfQ0885DDBTlZi4kJAJsQ4yIHHcS/GZ1Tu0C8pMxuQ0oyhOChGqCQqOBfZsxClzoI4PFAc/nJv96pcBcXFzIdVTh2DFl38aIDF29oTg17BojLdmqkD4belXIGXiXqwZ2ZJH6/Cd7bvTWhG7NL96b8Kwhdt@otD4lFu24UO8dzPMe/N6BjjfA8IZcIas@gO0DaMW@1Cqc/tZG89OmvjPQnFaPXCIQxBDNJTpPtJABLttpnye5Fp@J5nFODBOBQi7rviMeDOr5l4PomY9gNQtgj5KOBV8s8o7lQgCTyAdpZ0ryEfsipb/XsQ2MCkSz9gm07jjaNkX8cQyMBx6Yk9rApdPvkA0boZtglP6vSmNSnjbnokyA6dGq@NsQcPLNIuFwNlB9civ4T7j8B/wn3n8wS9ZOtTxpcJEOnaywOUj0edeeHRDBTP8w1P@Rz5kOQQcZmCgeBIadzbtfwa1cpto9vboN6rPqEATQxBITrsVT9xWn9tGG5@sVGI5HqAbGLhAiocQBdbxBOLzqBGbFvnptD251zsvCEQ@iVvHyjU7vvUQOnFSxjUEFEGBxfBh5K1xt4awi4QOAVGCCgHAaeKBpsj2JGvBIclEueQDh1cYZjnrG6l5kGSV@el@cG4hJHPUdsGFAjBAjdgyJBNsGH@S2HX2vjc4fnjg1h/LAS3cQxwMORoo0oYPJGU@G8pkKVFMqVJPnZBLSjuFq9WRTfH6qifsMrVMxrr/7D2V/74Ox3oV0szj0RLO8wKkK4qeBaOBAhvOZCWGW1aqheIQepDc3UHei5drl86vXWkMxGylczeDpYBPcC7@qNhSq/Hef1Q/vtREssB6QwrVahiNMqb5a8Xfgo5QgPorletKlPCF58zkAARnphNN2LNglHm1SrnHGwyZJoF6FMTiiTEx6Fh54syWTDiwbaU3DJO1ZPA6RTXKwnAjyFd6MgBg1Fhhf24pT2Kzy4DWdCvTRnPIeowKMhFLGRztqNhanXQ5kOMa0bAJAQbwHo8BvyysJNhqdIgS3gURyVPo/iNo8MOK8AAiMWXOGHm8YCIiMdGAR@MUH9ALRdMVEXRIVGefEvzX9i0nf0f8ptx/R8SGXeMZ288feP4thAzIYaaEj6UNJZZMioyTyzvFMBwzJHBC@T7dsg1bUubBZbIGyDe2rsRU21TLuVGmi4NAXvzfLukh5O477@gDMk7P7QHmkjO5stc6XJILJblD7XGYyeZeNx@6EDjkHW69i6a0VHUKltu2cZrp5kePbcme6pHbp3/roQlpM9o@0Kgjc8ydVYBM3pCkXdZhNv8mw2Y7iwLl4OFu3SOjskz2hUQP0XTKH4wJ48oAfDmN16pbdH8bth4lncXrQTo30WOxh6njiUus2Ah7VB/gffPkgwzLVnmiOdBIyidGsUozPn@/bA7oHUN3ZlAWPfAL8/g40Z0oZDykuSaajSlkMnslMribWTWtyL@ukHR2WfqjEtHsRX5wHMISPJnJs4Rsw6C5JrLk2OR/PTO/7w/B6H83u8Or@khd/MM1fNq9zzw5LOxGYQIOAsG5m7s4FFB77VuZWduawEzihX8QjvncUOLf3qYE63Iei2F1zuAn0kA5sLtiDjny3D/@oK9KPvvm/1aXi98fEU@M0AVyTG6IYU15/qjEHw/XhciCxILiDth@@ZFoTFy6n2UIQAMZYYl4WHmELDHILa7QbH7PuA76B5XG11i@5pCVaVey7Ik3OeZGfq8ip62OzopjbVOzEvZDIE1y/xEShsxK/er@DI6Ijp2VzXi0HfFQ98oRtHpPNA5SUkoyXP4/HlZMWDGAH10Eg55XB/Of7Q/xZrxiG@Kh@tBj0gGo3gcOy5gcOfw@lwys/JNvnFNh4f5f0Pr0k8VOBuhAAeeO@pJGfJxlexz6NYUKT36BGCsPJ8kfEYWx8iHpdzuw4/DEV3lxQqNxSp6teyMH//w@IaN1bVeIgqfJrkU0jvR5J3Ed1701yI1DiwGQvb@bAu5BZkXJ3RbsfCELnLyhqzrVs8Ad1onM5a0qs0FzDUICZxupFB6jbJF3EBNeN9@OKA02fwRYA9fdTkBOWXDce0vBunGPkMtGFIavFcQEgHKCEscpR72QiFEnwzBL@8DtJsL02zfSvN9lyaQQuYTzIUSGjPJenVAlbPqiow9e5oCXdGL9Sd4bOKbcNj2ZqDoxWXUSNaNpIseh4tA0OO6tHybgyYcrQTLT8kgxstH5PhLFr@FAyzthW9ipb9ZoEBHLCS4T66eywc7e1oeScWvxZG2pnu@unK0XJQpxBmi1sJI4AKLDdIjTjFZtleMUeODh0bCZVJhhTjJlF9onGYJP3S8M9vdKHbINATxzg3KDBLMGWu0wj1GDwd6Db808YXtOSy15vvHuzR6qYgCCaTAB0vHIfAgxgeic4zI54x9KUZDfhCBpFvlhfniIV6svfMjpc6UChV8nz6hD2Z5IFOjPzrELgxS4Su8fHi@/U1D4JX4PvlEyMvy@et7PjJUY5wTja@IFuI1JfRFYXCup7Pi1f74Rqise75QHg/uB@E1xKBDfF0kOFocg4TG9rDeSIhX1xAb4Tj0KAcb5RIvTeiEVfwWuYSb3L2SoaMIdz446uKE4qHWZtjQehZTzd4Kwv6BeLF6DXjdSFJlTc@yEKI50AL19tndEXSQ89I4Ti7SVJfsawb8uPyJIlzzbNJiCzjKU1jbcRTD5TXXTy76cPUVz/mBMdaYgggFDNIhfNX@wPkd5vL775A7SPhRgKLBOvFXelt8XplL3sj5@Ys2dsViJ5J9jC@UDgKUpihHLSDkGS@itZuifi45IML@TzRAPoNad9HW6AT3IG3m7oFh4VSgnM@73imguOZuhxRtyUS81z2hRYZU/Lg8IIHOZ0VbXVeecEXVTH60Pi2Zn5wBTvzFRyuPIRHBXBuoJy3cmds0SqXWdsGts1dkKUqZcYZOU2XBtU8cwR2T1O3wbQtOBw0jx4ePH38Neh0C4VC3Oujp7P8YavFsdagH@eQaal00B8sUFvUJN50gpPdOBzv9m1ntHZqibd4CWfWIAxokIpPfl4bj3u8LMTPb7RdiMfDhjDqwTqbNQNtjiuhqKNhl214eB0BQvRRbEPzgPjiLeA7SdpanO70aDbx/vVmk7qvZhMXLzWbXi@GVePPiMd/HllLjV2HbqzkF9JcCAIdR8AeHrDnj7ZP2MmjXbb3bOdT9rWDZ@z59tMT3Il@@OzB4/0dBr/dp8e7TJhbQomXd6FCCXh9qLd1vG@Rqel0lhHkHXs45XwnthPn7sfagD2y2zpOU2262uB@n1tkSx/VeKxdUEenOIZp0GVtA2OE6y3odjFQY1G46dCmP1zZzyBsC3TaAeq8A7tjdA0IK6DuOzR0198nxkwDahD4rb/pN8mFJLxIjJYO0fV/uALrAqJrEB7nbgCMxtdf0RX3hssj6B2ZeYgLng/G4Mnu0ZNjhoca7Bw8fbh/sn/w9JjtHRyB9fBr@08/AXzuH58c7T94hl4U8MnBw/29/Z1tcuAZSMsMTxt4NXZHK7MgY3DCSvsMZ77lIVR/YJsf9UYJnl1otP3RZdGxhdzH0Ezjjd6JVoSxi@ILbrmkqQIWW98@@uQz6POZ/hpnOP2pYFp/ID5z6XK79TTbpNSgsdSgvVUE//jAmKTEaT5iMGV4v4VeoVMIYmROMh84LeLpGDoTd3CNCo5988MKqC37oCGhNYCNoPwFK1VG99JEo8lNAlmD1NqmjedK8tT4IkLPglHv@0tNKgJhzFsrg0Bx98K@heNBSiVwALoHB9VLduTwACwTOPAALMsdUBTdx7Uj7P8p7mm32tiR/E0/hbBJ6Ib2FwmEYExiwCSeJZDBkNwcQ5zGbpu@19i@bgN2AvfM7o99gd3/@wj7KvMO82ufYrY@JLW6bQiZzDmTc4K7W1KpVCqVpFJVaVXmuBodXqF4Fmv84dfLwR4dC4sX@sO2R7vYdYkT9xt1qSf0vV4YuqFLtw@xloduSPTCZhBQkZDy48083S4PDJ/vhAOZyEeJZNsGOVMgbNp41CDN3vgiVUwFbkA7Ia89CoVdcrLiGI2D/F7A9z51ul6PTaAi0x3iPbGOUXJKW3L5oO9LIn@QQZ8YEO9qi@Ohy@3KVaH/2HJQcnuqRk/aSNKdhcoE7XsIbE8h8I@AAUCZ2E6nSTMVeaQimH5bsrId9oEjUW/7h5kf2Ll11fRjBaTVlv1r8PWrI4nsxvZJyk6RsIMu@uoPYVlJR5nt/hDGOIlVumEGpWDzoj8YBdyHdrwFdOJE0xzkxokNavuiiCtrQzoka@z1e0al58DF99R6Dkz5mFqJ4/nsXIuv6OpR4HyYhNnuDtHxzvvXvnF25uIh0o2P6hdYCNNZOSo/JyPChNefViQ7/hB4Y@F6aWt3@zTzxxcXry1kscC3hiqjQ/wPjIl1wfCgcz4yWBziukuONHXdVHh1jqWlDZ6UljjKFTDYB14EsK973SjqNDY3nv6OHjPJ7/Tx9rbEpTIomeRFsuGFHUk3V9RVlS6VORPSBMSQnYAsyHpbfXEJppbXr9FLBnuhCBTpoRzBfXviMicpQlTrzq/aIFnknZqyuzV8R2yRRUV03TB6v5j9kftsb5eWt5xcZFAiDHLaSkS7CnLBcQyzFJqvpsDtPgwO5Pfjwa0/iB1PDz8EbfdBaD@EW2b5flg8LRmwHg/2jwfA8uT2D4GFtrv3A@ZJchqa5nTNnO5CWlvTPlzjl6m@o7EHYHDuRQ2KBmrUdtWjI2oVxtnmAo4JJloQ1Y53K0dHIsX7EygLcg@3DC0pBhH2vHgfWdsGPRJ2Wb1oMmMv8@JJfYlZtKl/Dw3mmcS7R1TINYgr6aGFRXSxdjsYs9STMwstIcj6ngSiolwcu29KBoV1CfgO9oCAbNRpRgOtmc1M8@QThKYRuKSby2tj04afLKx57sabKocTE5BpE@R10LNkdv995PXxhqqHF1gY1gcb3IKVNMw3sE@oQcUDyJjNxnvwgW5RXYpG9rzATivaoeFXPr7C/nmGIkbiRTivhQ2xLhfHEjVeHy@oZQ4ZJOI04KGlp0xki2ZIUCKevmyaHepEk54dn4JgkYl3F742uQKKn93JKYyooefJkl6Qm2NtgbCpKyzPUDsrYRfvz/QEbaHXkuIhWRVI2weryvxzquJZIlaTovnMxqhEgLy2uvrse7CTrVDFMz8Lm@eQpPwcXQ5gfx@BDCchqfeBc6sHrkqPGOAB0rFpvRowiYKw1Jkxp8TaTpORiR/gwnohQAaDmuN1kMlaHTFO4DYbOs9IJnTKMtUGYwjrhvKomaL@3cPVoUD@bn3zP14fDzbMhKaDd2iV/64/DP3IK8@I1GJ8QtfW@Dd/OOxRNvZnukQoNrkxPehsR952bPDKrcJEOm8zW9KW3klsdusqXQNVQurFLN4Ai9q9YlK9lykUzabuVfcrYomCHbZjusjUMOUYsmc@6D2EAMlg0kvg9EE@fE/CDfgPOLgKJJCJvPlsoo3zXdyIIrBqrtN9NtIsVMrWQrL322HT62GADzf1JBQp9ykUJC1s5XDPmaVZzxdj5QG5cNCzoZSbymRTVBS@oUIXIcVBcG/id2PCQk8NZSmJ7jWdPtpH4cGWP2btGVlOernCen7tpUWt67kj97L@8sxdapZSAiZfr3cZXg1vWr91@hfXbdEVg1/Px83J19@FWH0unuGFn0854mxhrZSjIJ8v4O@6eJknzpUIvqLouacpIbJ8V6AQiyLahxfnBV@XQZvmDfSQSHCpWLpUXIgudqPSZX3trNQr5YuX9d5ZEZ38Rsul0XJh2cYPT2EWBRnDJ/P10RnOqabW1e9dC7xClq76k64hglxD4Ms7bxj098sHb2LaOFwAoApM2nqTQp1vf51Dazb0Pcn2/BtbqslcgRxr4QLJmiOvoAL6vZM@GdUxrQAwg15xYTUbjunvxLHm8tmrwahPKSrgILKWuA1urTnlxpQnjQJkqQcqLCFdeh@Oozw2Hgzx1wlbUWcKvFwroO@kY4CoY0kSh6nTVAp9ChFR6ctVP7PCrO81LxAJvO74loqJzU26/BhYLcySFg9NObwhOUzkz/ARD0DgZ0CnDVgFrdxDcvuwoPn4XsAH/kI6qhH5yZCBvEUrRUxB82/xjfybqPwmEIAJP8drrqxUccqVFywk2XeQlAsYtiy@8cdjBnSr5E6Zw8YibK6vFAEnS3GiEVYryQTf526QnEwr@CdbkCnQ21QzdH6HsxNJ6JxavoVIS@pSStrCn25UzDaKZVQxldkgxdx3qYGaLtgevfNhWE3Ejt/tAtJMi7mIHPhI/r2y/mVdf1jHOs808pyemUrPxNKznM5IRbmyMMFHmTbMTKn0tyjfnUhF2dypukqCFi9Z6OlmFpYkUd7iQ3nD7KjfCKLMW7ormSt1wmYsIWOkfJ7R@5wyHyujGVyn1zld8veK7HmNZSzv63j9@GvJDvLJeFbamiS4NNsLuq8seVOuTEE2SwE1heDidKmeUIOqJH0wpTiBFRzq@WnYbpUiKMsFJXFozKS2Nl@nsnKR8cpOosFejFMDa8YYMahEdS4T4cbksAj1UPK8AYJgIqMJNXK3VOGJLDwxwGKueVUte0FODXBoWnKIl9Av8hb/qMEeR07lS89OnGPMx9x49m6OE4iE7nxqNpni0gTdRfijbNQDs0hU9yQJcbaQODC0wLpOn32w26gGn9dywhQUSlJM0V2nSEpHGQqKfe/rQky8s/6eW7LeeLDGHnT9sSjjNsMjLywr5uA@8sNRiJGeKF5NeDUYdPHUkRZ8N@RCLWOGrKzicUsE0ZjZs1YVLXs4v4tP0iEdCmXFIUK@QQORKCG86nTQmQw9YPs3KFpR4xKMsla5N2GFBoyZZyvsZu6Lq5BPTWG33zGR4J7j0YOUDgde089asEYLYfVjcVPbgbyMkvTp6DeCscRgStuwrD9fBc3fdt7gee6LQv5ZwSDZtTwOzmefPY8crIBIKmEF4wCuFp5blnE23OSz4QwCdMU@TvQfgDf9a7/X860yzBiUMYRFa@gPr/1W1rKOfH0IjHCRlfFkEv2w@1fDJit3YNHlATOil3Do8nEYcBj@4vzMx8VNOitzLTy0ik6boauvgxYSUHmctPt4OkwHFhgmgOmBhS79ERBlyRFxlOjsWeJCa5dLVEQBNTDOiXE2ocnQ64@CJvQMabKsLoDiY5Cosl4rgQnU1@x66BycnYUAusdEFFAIqKOkh3Cw5KH5D@EgZMPUGbuneiYH0q9PYwWGuz8MQPpGBKZeoWIG7tDBx2@rNVE73Dv@WD6qCHh@f3T4obpb2RXbn@iMGw/KKaaueHu4D9JFn6bzqfkhfEiVa1AyRQlW@eCTqPzy/qhSq4nDI1F9936/CtAA/FH54LhaqbmierCzf7JLp@8AQRwcHov96rvqMWQ7PnSpVlXMisqJwz3xrnK08xZey9vV/erxJ6pxr3p8gJXhqX5ZvC8fHVd3TvbLR@L9ydH7w1pFYMOs3WptZ79cfVfZzUL9UKeofKgcHIva2/L@fqKhhx8PKkeCjASMVm5XAMvyNmxhsSZq5271qLJzjA2KnnaAeIDgvitq7ys7VXyo/FKB5pSPPrkSaK3y5xPIBIlit/yu/AYaZ9nfoQr0y87JUQVDISElaifbtePq8clxRbw5PNwlWtcqRx@qO5VaUVj7hzUi2Emt4gq8c4@qBhhALUiH5@2TWpXoVj04hjnj5D3aOzjQyR@BMIBlGYruEoHRDAJbC0Q6PPqEUJEO1AGu@Pi2At@PkKZErTJSAS0qdo7NbFAhEPHYbKY4qLzZr76pHOxUMPkQwXys1ioOdFi1hhmqaJDxCVgHKj2hVmM/AV78CMxqKc51qTtFdU@Udz9UEXOZGzigVpXcQmTbeStpnsWIu4YSJeijzsC7NBUr7elP1z6GmpzWyMzW0eiISTuHuxWYkWXcqlSUcAKzznoilJKZBjONToTXWMialn9@1WkEvXYffUx1MVZ8XIYdF6@XcfBujlPrgduVpH6FCqTTjcaHcgM2urVGw3EfUzKGxvdKSDX4Q7kc2Ua8TAB33qj42dhgum/GCLX1VB50kqEeHkBgTqb@UzZ98y59R@RyLV8WQ@d9BKxURyEfm1zgUQqIRnJ2xEtFoipJM0HvgWQHKmgr8NlmA/WkaBlJmfoh/OndRi88ORgfQDqzuiuXw00soRF89VU1XAmFRKA/MiJB0KYqs6Hv/9ax82Z1uOfPdvr9lu04qgzlHcE@sGM73yl@7ncSxTPJ8oQsHTvLGP6h2nfTEkafP0uSCdkv2SG1zMY/jRH9OAobjvmAWlOqipTVUmlpP@XiaJHkChnaAt0rqJNxzfeu/Ev1I@7m8ivPi4nvb/V3HltoL4ghaWHCq1O5M/p5e8YZYIBRLA4gSSAjZORyRhllb6Iz30DGC8x0E7TQ8gfm6guf5nUgCSxkr7yuWSfOxsNgbGIPcvjNUfnd9sneHohOxPb5@uqLtaKlw2794vLvJ6yH4sZS1LEBzOOwTqMkY5TswMKHRooRrztif2LgXA4zYix21Wn0EeM8aLuNuCUTCjJsbog37PTQRC/lIx1SggJwzFuKX2eOTMkAdqypDrbm0hvTEt@DtRLxgDRm6U6o18b4B2Hr4a@GuG6QZCDJYhRJFzgXdhck91J7ylSUNjcUuAezZFOKjzmMm6YBqbrIfha9a@lN8rbRiyGbMuJ4pW6nkoDEfBILoewqejyy31OcEakApuhh8OUXyW/w@EkGuKNwd144Ko9qQMY9XRL11JEyWja6LiGf4WU5GFRN1bQpUMvvSKRo7El1sg4MYowGQgXvP0Eb3zjgoo4jkqySLGBfLzriG3MqBu9AOEXJsfIdOHdWcySUooofIt9VVArBsHSQE6baja7DUlk@6TgWipwxMv0UPQj@v5AmM@Bvwo4ToEfUMoIAPoqSBJVpBdtXIkpwow4ajNONiJrmp08RmDuzYy50w@TpzZj9a4AEsncm6sMnCnvYtmcQAJkcFRvm@NUmaRcebJ1epxxZHM9Jes3LgS3kXKGmiim4mbUzl5ZdrjpbwRdHOKxrMirch6LiNW/czmnUw5YpsZUXT8IUg3NU/I/cEilA9IAnLr1gq9UkZ@XlKFNyQIZaMiaclo6YBMvSu3tP7ZaEESIzJvvlyZciFIDeQnym20mXhPQFm@fGIy7STCyOKQoeRgfHbTJOPjJk3TkZYnZ9hPOkRcoQvEdkdIMTRJehU6i@CJqwn5ChCFYSWR1GcQZR3DpZIC1Nqzcae9JMIodq7E96HJbeZ62WypHlAB8SQ9NdPiveeRNAufu4ZjOL5ZZqfRdtF7EyVkvI8nhnSrPfH8LS0cN2A45uMHGy4qNUOvi98Goo4xfCfBYMpUZCLfqhGlw28e6dphmOCE@ohcEIvRVaWeIPatKljxaiHJ5knFkTNjCv4tEtpXQMxssFYW9GKZtAEwpLSkTcFGvi9pZzMUFlyFCfKBiEenNBNptUD5476OF30x/@hnM/LoF6Lb@lI5MaIEkXyJ1U7VGMx@aImz7oh6TRgK5ADYimRIEVadpQFeboF5KdpF1TKoqOibFLqSU/Xo9mUmUtBRVFjCtrB@Zby0BnIpVWZGhQHSy0sLJKqMzacN3duxmjaKHxY2uROu1pkbLBi4jSE7V0xCeWm/rpEz5JJX/pSYijB77gGbdcgiLCuGbFc9VpOUf4oU3Bx8AftkydKKxkWt4A1W@09en3iBeV6lCG/Wt6o9CfwA6gmQvGOYLRsP/Uv@g1dvpdrxP0Aw/2aRjUfcwSDx8n9Igd1hn2b0K6DogSWkam1iR65vgyHIYN3/W5ZNEIzRWO/IFtmimMhpPyBYeJIM05GgFG114Sfw@SMdJ0meerUSEr7n9K9ngFp3hv2WeFWYX5RB8BSAG3lbCgYB/SETkmGc6nxakM5w9lMHA8FxnhOfdY7MUwfgkkomOYGMYKmSmzBLMRuDO7F@N6a@y2KAbhEAMt@bs@XmwT2vTZ9fAmYZAir9BSYEMU1vNGUT5FGWMcQnyY3E/ulRf/YuwBgZ9Av/BsFrfMYgQScW0VbSnk/YqMMgq4kHlgQDKaJDFIsaADs1A3BrQxTkKNJ0/uowZZ/sCiSIbZm@JKHJE2bHzw1jq7ASKnMXFwUlkUiw7F7cAlSHlk5@9nWP979rM0@PEQlzVnKJh2JGTbQPo@UjWBSnhXa8K81kSZYyp/f8SsrDy21xIELM0yOTPuDLZTauVCHigBz694rNUfgjBOJagnTT0Ww1F/sPhI6t0rO2ZGZptF66bjfNcQmJmtBJPlUotIW5rg46RoJfFJME2cYmRpBjyE21d61myeJOK41MDxVmpMvkOH@2gW2U3pSUX3d4vHPk6K12jRqyYaPaQIdwxSWtTf6w1oeON@CSJh8vaqQRKjgSKjMeFHA1SCTJpKj6cQcZ/EPUGPFlAO620B7cz@uZeoSSM5FfJUJcWCXCI9MXA7Om2CXBq00fgCw8TxClcLKb3gHLsTOsorZM4xyDAmMEBcFfuZSA/FGtyosxJ8RLcDtO0GWgsVUBLB05Zp4aCD/muCUVR@qdyRFg@NSaZwVmRIYw0JdhWU6yFIyt8cXuuNMUGZIgUM8Rmk0C2akk0Xj2/Vz7YF8gEELk3J0tI372JjHLEM2MAfM6kxxjVwVJUsGRtR8YHQINEAYwF2KZ2uz9tVXP0FQ@Z4tG6Qwwg2EPzZxp9lWQLDea/lNbWxyLg1wSyOJDePNkdktrhIxFD8juSXQ5GXurRxBQA@YwzlSwWAgGFNCXs8FKDQOybnxRCVfQQFSwUclvCRoqJGdp4z0pGoMsPzVSNHflaOlyaMzEwgsLCYnSdCBNYss7NEUGCim4mLkePF7PZEOWBBrHifKQ5dIXslTkPdc0xAuk8570QSpV4Qbl5yMCU@X3ViiZq/KfVl3kjNJ1OBPhrDeqaQTF3Px1Jj1a6sxIvGSgI9HLPWWCKQwjER1lLh5/6Ra4oZ8lzbhBqbjNgqQ9pn433XsMuEfVv211BsklO2WmMoeKZnuNp@NfiKlVhQ9ocDsItFOjLA2O0/3VplmaowkXcFUFw65exi84aQVqwpnOqxWbjTVZH2dIACtaftt8WH4729WNjX84kyNLr0h6v5fB6Z@NwMfq9sq1GVFPRz8dy59lW3mxvc/Gn44TxHst/36UqADbWD9qFLYFCE2f6wwzdDIA6QFXNnpCMr7vWv2m3zCgY8ocTOg27jnDIagqAJKNBGLx@OSQFEIOUE@wUbiO37IvTou/F4oSmhqGMoKI0mwdcpdXoG5MEPbbTP1idVBAwFs7JmgnnLKW19wxkEbzahzqLwxc63yDw59dbvdvuu@IgXCmOkgLm7ZIG9PbNAnrPgCSN5916FFI/WFf510DX8ijGLyesITk1M6p4JFRceY@Mf@Z3KeGCn6p9TMK1Ak5exmcsYn9oVqU7KkcHiHwGW@RDQflTuS29gN4lOycww1csRHD0BRs8K7sy9TyyLQzoxSbPv50aizkY3S8EaoOkOrQVULHvqXmrJPdk1cVOn40IbaZhnGBInjLnyuBLoavavE4vXo3b7cVKRrgHgjv0hicg3ofycQKQzABqBcvgBPTGK9r9lYFjvJQKK8AIHL@uYljtYoIEFLOtJs/T7jV0ul8XCYHlZlMvb8JDJiPJ2Wezih@1tsQvv2/j@tLSyulpkmbvrfIOP2@rjndgGGKThXG5eDHfhFdJK6DeG1trYxQu50oJbXGiUNreKYa5e3ka3fnj627//59/@479yZfnyP/iyTS/1zzpTNpvNLTS/LTy9K@J7ffdsceG8vjA4W@wUkcv@TlHD@9VRxovMR7PDcyvNs4DxlexI1T6bos/IokJd@HfpDX8D6bIh0s0wl5ZfQ745imRsuukb3330ozyHLby6dCC5lQck0gB0gup46J2mjwZ4MN8AJQEXtAPl8ny2ohT3GA5GZ9CnKmkZiYfWrNc@@rREkRTQFxdmrEzQC/0easCvac3LzbMsD36DUUPyb@7zu7Cz3R@LpVNbLOXFkiuWUin6Kay9hK/OQi5A71zOBtuBVMqFlOhoAc0MRRjQQo/2D3TXToLclrVAV/YgJBWmgjKzF5yrd3/kLMMXroUdaw4v1hSsIqFDJiyS/rbQu4Nu@QY57lIxVxtaKDTkLoYqM05UdP/iEsgL2RAgqvmSCbLRhyrxpI88kvEpp77IvrboNiECjGQ9erNH4x4/wFy00JM2z7G9FF5zRObz/BXnxiI7QxPamML1RwjQgQpvJ/PkSbiYXrTYyttoJTWTvbDN9knmY1uHiT9Stulc6A9hMAFbc5uEW@hJvxZpyM3HKyIV6OMVo6pU0vZbWEaRy6vuKBhIdwWqHQfUN13bHY8k7FECxHA4Zv/G9AgjRYGKFJXoFr4sayJafWw6j4SedE2HDnayfHJkECH32YaxfZsY206OvEQUOzAPEFLalK/tBd1QRl0ZErE73vAcbwf02nSh2ojPzUifh1epJjDutzXSWYJMJufReIampAdDr3PpuSJ90D8eepMqTFuw8hk1sw60EEMwIRI4@GTVs5qnEOYWyS4hiuimkOUQXl7Qncjr0bhvU9rnBLtUDQUZdgUHQYydiJL@bayvEnSMuPoHOsFEeUp469NIKWJJ8qKlkYSUMt1maJhNDR1L1WCOHT1wUhajqkem4gVZ6Aon2ks6@AVJ3sUYAbLulPQClK4Iay@xfpydOn7Pi01Og66lHP1zRcHzIo5nuoqSrZEsdQlqIbrxDrGCdeTneBQInptUOCNrzrbnTkN5nVvanEcoyLe2xc95ItAX0NEFZuQZIk56AQvLxAwV3YGRFVWy/AcI7a7XAfwmN94EWfE0bb@azzn1z6e9syX7tHd7@tUhTKRIVrNsRqTlYbaSWHKswMyYc2OvyiotVKEGT3vxDKc9wT4sBgkAkZxd/5w7u80BQqdpvGH@NM0EiXUZYpJ7uL4cgs9NoZmOY5FLW3POkqM6335VcATMrfSLfcgfHP4FLNSmktT0sM8ZtgEU@en@fsUuJ2FufSX/fKXwHHZCHX@cGfpXON9mwqtzfwxLiRC3szD1nH6NcUOMEHfj0CvCxzG0k681Yd@TUDopSREqhznVY2m2gjJZ5gnID1SmcKno4uLoPB4ePuKG3xXAciovxYJi00GD@2ycP8P@JdbjhSjXkt4hzJFoZcA2IqRCzSBkdfnKfRzqqOGySH5OWbGDsVsJCHRvLm3MFr1@LyMXa052sYiLaPSa6a7n1/PJMTo1RGMjdEEuphbnRWHr1Yu//vfh7@lRemsl93EIv6P07@m19TQ/wgO8PVNv1@mt9CZmW7tLT3KwB4bHF3/9Xyi/9SeAgymTTfiztapgrU3SW5kSFblNb63BQ2FlBer9v7/8BdqwwDs2vIt1oeEKQqyoKLLj9Yh3IV1UsZW8LV2MxAo5ZiEMtjCEvTm8oGHUeGU9T2q6tLSquPZl5CtljyKneDLMGpGpEGsylD0FrIy4QAkryDBIZULRFobthjLbQOaN0BRfnmTXQtgBfJHmHLpKbbrxJESToQXeFkEH2lwj7Of5YSv/KqXNOzZSyqakqJaQuLWTsnb9WfH/AQ)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/z2hvp)

PowerShell has `#` line comments and non-nesting `<# #>` block comments (not used).

PowerShell treats CR as newline. There are several other languages with the same behavior, including Nim, Raku and C-gcc.
I use CR on line 21, where block comments in many langs are already open, so it affects only Tcl, Python3 and its derivatives,
Coconut and Sumerian, and PHP.

CR is replaced with LF in copy/paste operations, so I use BEL character in the test driver input and then replace it with `tr \\a \\r`.

Coconut treats not only CR, but also VT and FF as newlines, it is separated earlier on line 14:

```
201-1|>print;exit 0
```

`201-1` is to avoid two consecutive zeros in Whirl, `|>` is to avoid `()` for Prelude.

PowerShell #331/PHP #191/Python3 #1/Sumerian #241 code is on line 21:

```
#...\␍331;"${print+191}$"*0;exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
```

`\` escapes CR in Tcl, its code is still on line 30.
`"${print+191}$"` is PHP. Note that `${..}` also works in PowerShell, but I guess in PowerShell it just replaces variable
named `print+191` with its value, which is empty string.
`+` and second `$` are for Pyth. `*0` creates an empty string in PowerShell,
so pwsh prints `␊` instead of `$␊`.
`exit` is for PowerShell and PHP, noop in Python3 without `()`.
`?>` is required in PHP.

PowerShell requires the code after `exit` still to be syntactically valid. `f` fixes `==` in PowerShell. In Python3/Sumerian
I use `'''` string to hide the rest of the polyglot. In PowerShell `''` inside single-quoted string is like `\'` in other langs,
so `'''ss'` is equivalent to `"'ss"`. The rest of the polyglot is hidden inside here-string `@'...'@` in PowerShell.
`@'` must be followed by a newline, `'@` must be preceded by a newline.
I don't use `<# #>` comments because Sardonyx has `#> <#` comments (also non-nesting),
here-string gives cleaner solution.
Python3 and PowerShell strings are closed on line 609:

```
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
```

`#>` reopens Sardonyx comment.

```
Abbreviations (ASCII):

BEL  Bell             \a  0x7  7
LF   Line Feed        \n  0xA  10
VT   Vertical Tab     \v  0xB  11
FF   Form Feed        \f  0xC  12
CR   Carriage Return  \r  0xD  13
```

Comment: @ais523 I tried your [Lua suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46961925#46961925), but it didn't work out.
There are a lot of langs that like Lua don't treat \r as newline. So we must start Lua code with `#` to satisfy those langs, 
but Lua doesn't allow statements without side effects, 
so `#".."` or `#[[..]]` is not possible. But even if we could do that, `#"`/`#[[` would still break Haskell-ghc and GNU Pascal.

Comment: Practical languages that don't treat \r as newline (break when `tr '\n' '\r' > polyglot.poly`):
Python1/2, Ruby, Perl5, Perl6-pugs, Sidef, Julia, CoffeeScript, Octave, Bash and other shells,
zkl, gnuplot, 
Asm-as, C-tcc, Haskell-ghc/gofer, Curry, Granule,
Simula, COBOL, Pascal, 
Ursala, AutoIt, Brat, Make, CMake, Prolog, SQLite, Pari/GP, PicoLisp, Nial, 
Elixir, Ring, Joy, dc, 
Agena, Objeck, Sardonyx.

Comment: The method I was trying was to rearrange the entire polyglot so that the second line (counting lines using`\n` as newline, `\r` as non-newline) didn't start with a `#`. I made some progress with the languages that existed at the time, but didn't manage to get everything working. It'd be much harder now because we have so many more languages.

Answer (score 5):

## 78. dash, 2176 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw(([5]{} )))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f  2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}(({}5){})>)}{}({}())wWW'#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
<3>
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
ai
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
ai fir at fir
#sseeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉p(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0_"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": p( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":"77");"7";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"# xi xi xi xi \++++>/ xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi xi os
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004585 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2260 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14.
**78** in dash

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLd9tKcl4bJ/9gNm2Q1wBE4kWKevEhybY08R17pFiynWOSlkEQJGGBAC8AipRl@mSbnCxmP5ss53/MNr9i/sjNV93gQxIl33uSRWgRaKCru55dVV1Nd5xk8OuvOfqw0yi47gdRylIvSVk39q@82GDPr9mB4yeVUlmSOFQcdceuH/ZZOvCYH47GKev5gZdIrpOyBhtlsxjUYDkWe05XgEm9KGY0hA0vA@YzdzRincAZGC4LfMAeWzuAT6IhwaRePIo9XBMWel6XJSPP9Xu@y3Exb5p6YeJHYWIw371kEz8IWNcLMGBJgFvEZGycrLwS6AypG0kMH3d0h9zFU94DTOjNWfZGTsxZjtiI8z/nfBI7oxGIlHLsDISn/tBLmJ8qCfOcxCc5YkjihV0urdFCwhFzwlUu2ZXvMAf0jmM@d@LFKdgz@Lxs4MUepnQIeT92hkydxH4KEZAwD9mp58TsPPY8DVigBC9xnRHouIUSyCLCkBIjBldWraYcnRwrUJoYYTijVMrF5fN/@VlymFFn@YsqvnVZrkpHf37JbvItaoMKTAbFjmLV0Vj9O0vMVsvDd2p3zH48kzCrBKkEzIxGqYmZnTgFecuWflUyRsEKWla7o4kVQxJQXeiCvQrZ@yLnyx3HsQcqliJ1LsFyEIV9SBOsxuOQpBGyLQsKcKOwmxSZdwWZRaHQUDTh8j0f@FBZQgpxOhCP45LkxSLg4sQygOVl8pzjTaJgzOEwMknJ/CATDKUZX/XYe9Zz/ICGoJ@mElTHXjIOUhozDruk96Efel2Dzclwoy4BDaMroHMwKX@BdTNcWW2cKABDDRFnlbr@8Ze/dvt9zHPoulHczYz1PetG7ngIgh1OrANDJHONQifgZAGuSNjFcCC4cgK/66SEPrzOUHAiONZJNA66LALCeOJjYQ2cKyzGXs9zU0@YeDROQWORDZ1L4SN8YbdgfOh0oFiOgOPmbOvs4AW05HrCYPThOO3tMH10xJTE/KTu76n7T1seaNMMbSNvmv0qrM3Y4K/wpDxmOO8Pl/ok6zn3I1pFwWgwhs9AT5iM4E1iEqbrgJ2EnEoKv1dkHS5o7olg6HyJTjwl9lgH63rOGLcRYQM0Xqd1m82w1Okc7raJed0VC4N1wsjS5J6TCKIJEHPayHnCpkNC7vQdoEozhg4FQwIjf3ObtcsQlk6zdTy2o3d8aIfsAK4mU8YKjwAvlwQMZhPaW1kUQ@cas7jCRS81yfwelDyE3cbXzPVoMWBVeMLPEZIxN4zEhx1FPWbppUrlB8pPY/NQ/2g6@lfzUR0T83fUfMh63oQFTtgfO30YchRiiOO63ijNVhA4SVKskbtukL/UM59uJAMpf3AXN/dtmbdfwUHeR2gv89AOmT0ENYSo9QCrnDlxn69E1vVjrJfg@i52AFzdQS5/JpBbBHyWHyBhHphgZN7Uc8cplhsMeTLw3QFsl6gLxYIV3vEuerxaxQ6Xo/cWqIkYu/GsJBnm4hWR8eAUOmn0/jzw@jRV49YLrvzVF4/P7CTDNRNHCxLhoVbeGqZjwPYyoSGan1EmAfc3D918ZS3Si4U8IeCfKTDF3i9jKAz27PdDAnHCRdhf8Yx@EioIFX7iQ@oUwMnWz1@dUDz44IkcBnIXsWzVmUfIaDA8C9DUMVeC5LmDiOkhUzIaVJnH0y8gy0xilzf0lSRC1gzISSV58a75RF9EbnY3oLLGfTiOUimypiy3i4hhQQITCsdBgIdxyJeY6mk3sDXXSxIDCwayNSgbAXVywdNmtwHTQRxNmDfTqso6dL9TIS/GHX/6/1AjLtElruBqRQ381W/Rwz3AuSJkORPdPQguuxfRkPw8@8A5Jnqfx4gNPcQDaXSdDuDpdJfJTj0aeSDplidRQCeSc1Wr8oROUYwvkR@qN8rTp0@VPaWhFNHaR6tGrX1qFdDa5y2dtwjOoBYfUeQt6m3yEfSurcya85mnWptUO6Ws9as/Up3m3l65XXSadnYv0V1DMEHsALRON8yjaPU6NTVNbkzAqNHpSYL9cyjnNVI@9tqnSNxDgrjcOEgLZC1JFsIo3/al8rKnJHLV9@YQ4jNG1@uzCHl1Kj7gjR9eRmSj5nDeurAMu3JrCux37o/s@cmAX26B3iPrfg8fnQw7PX5ZA7CXpQHIKWiPRHLhrowykSiC5U842DAKI0EK5OWHjvmW3wxEj3X03HbSt4h57mHN9z19t2x2/NDseL2HII@fP3/FYXqdjv8QEIRCdM/va8DicWedzJCbDe4FcXZL6ufjOA30rpnS3fvvf@tC@vd1M3CuE2Tzl4vGBYRGetJ7D6oqG0oP/LJerV/GAXZ6P5jDdSiDd4JFY/1ce@ytB9uHWkO@wQOlQQB/ApHBz903bqyLYNz15vf1k3IZ3s4FxOjQH@qw7C3D4grEI@U33Ps8MMudhEZMQxufOIicrim2or631KiQvTd1@lF4ba5ENiPu/AZS5zkHW@4908E4HYsrbTh/pDt/RN/HFmQGaVUOn9tH2e0BeBCx9ZDtimVDrlo/DpxLs0PNix6a61kVzMR@H7vb@f0hsA9nI8f1zElCtwf9RzhORlyRvPUQGLLHOBDXh0D80EVkDZeNhwDBYsAvv8fquBG4TgDTKwvDo3qPviIj/45UA6dzTfFs8PsNiLD2CwWmw4fU3ULBKjM9Wm7IlpWl0ejh8a6bjd/dXT9aFKH4BG6EvbP3o6CEyOIPIYJSd6X5oJH4kb7c/yXCsigfWOeMnCsH@UHgJLCVNJO4dwUN8ctjtkshwx0HTrxsPWa5d4ia78Ef2sYtR458N0JwF6ZKD4G/1lpDyvvu5kjLaajAyC/LofSUudGXSIMoEn9/1JdGbkq7pwfM6De4J7Fxoa3hil0Y0UNCc6MJfR9cwYPoyhPX9WHp61qqfoP70QNuEki@7w/vuj@y1g9@AueDy3q3eLmWqtQN1r7fY2@iKMbONWElw3pUPWuN@cx4Zbw2TowzduYHUfKoPLBvTxJxXW/KS9BO7Duh7pINr7bXD1tLGA9x7JBfH1CwE/SjYGunbzq4PGgF47hH3j67/1Ynt3BStv1DJ7VIa6LQzu4PuvhL/P3IQKgqAp/uU36zaK43lh94tGwz8DCb2AHQyPUsHls7CxuLE2@tcQF3BnMYu4OJc/2oCf4onjwk7Hk82aMqPk@lHyXmh2g2H0fTXeuv@IbqLa@aL8pYSTEr9uOdH2fF3WRxfpJ7Fbqxx4ta8206y1GpbTxEQEij2GAcTlWdQkHTJDGIXEs/BNgcitewqYwoyuMJg49POSy2gs0my99M96w9e8bqTN6TWbstZuUFraPpiBef34qhzbzTrucVXVfySivcY5bCQb0A@l0L6tyC6/n8Juhcss5CZ8grl9Sec1oV5VE4YKqJD5ywi0z4XejzCoQbxaLIJyrJfNfx9791s6OCvgcmh37iBBAEHW5FQ28QTfYF3gz74Wjk0FEDzYEELBA1Cv3FIUsmfuoOxAkB4sO74/OdrLybHbbh4ZRS4BUqhFLRhc116qRCaYKabuQJY8sQL0bNmULQHQ9DNvG76SAx4ElD1@Pl43lJE5TEBBamcUTGWmSvWNejbJCXWL6Modsgii55ZYco@fvfRFEbnT6ZELXn6PkpywpGBqdr80qy60ZjUD2f5KsXRxmISkJG6jCGRK6xVDzxXmPuwOHVdliiPq81ExpRb35xeMb0I6bQGSGVnqt@T80fvv3j@6bVrn9nQxMbRJOqXVxu8k/6tp3IRTYHqc7Irla7LXQvexUm56dyxhadR/Hjl4VRidXEVGpzdc1rx0N@lMXtzpvw2jE/IAgpM6IzojDB@sCjxqcWi6aeV7GzHPop089SVqGDVA8iQUscfjE6mqQ6KA3JT9k3NiBb0V1mVyw8CYEEVHof1pf7@dWCivnS64z5xuOqZJTKdc5O/qJea/BW7HUjOpxpfmpN2mYyl0qrNf3JKk0htigG@DOTVs7Rn1/e5I2G9e1bApcqyzOlygtetLzzN6evTo/Ozg/P351BjDPBZe44iofO0kWQEYwCRLxBFPDTLsgj9r3kx27jCfcb0pMMUFVZ3mE1ZlsMHurJwrFkYpV1OS@aoo97kkXfnc7MffR8lrk6dsq1nSlWSVbdXHFuACQ8rMkx/OqceBjOzRp3xdmRWR0M6WCIgy8IXjytY@x2L4cXAt@nZwg9Y2MVirO6hFoPRLwK4IxuASOIXMvE7P@I8hHiyI8pJ6gfUQ5g6UfYVxAfH756/e7t0X3cK2gzmHsgCwtZ@XnB0RQ5Cvxgj1s4HWLN7SbKDiHnjgF@fyAq406wdG3JoshNltQjxxxgbdOi4CWAhBY3Iz9isMMggSPtduEZOtcpORZ4VFHXXhS35RwEYCziXJHJEsEm9fuHUXAcE2SS7mcxOM/h@MzJuvPclmf@4y9/FWe4rRTtf8/aPbT/U7Q/mSSg@4d@gsaFaEgs71@dsgTRSjA@dKYrPFHAoIDkh2MkU0NI8IoLhMAFsUt@l/OozfeQJ5QAYZLnI2fH8XlxWx2k6WjPNCm@IzHvGbww6E2hB/hKA6ms@cuYjtThn82tytambYJI/Wo@IT@p6VOVSkyoaXswIenKH9U/d1xWq9WYnLhO4NW3qkKQZt75VJY/LwjNA1YSqUCTYQyGLEegr5ENU/NOwdZoKK1CxVZYu4ooL/SCQKHyBkA0eh1m8pARiaJMVHTo401T7lSv5ykO8oswYkOSE/9hxXwiHROJuTVZume7oBc9vBTl38otjVU1yB8IjBeu9uR1psNgIf@1xnJCtP9DtJstS//eXvejgIXtHN4/@1fvntwTL@zgLIyoOnkMWplaMktl097SVtaJnE0FamlVfMOUWAdYV67nf4lGyeGLo1c/n5ye3Tu75pDKXTCFKY1aoaUbxWZ70VDu2PxcpM@PzbM3z4/nglylKuu6S9W6ye8S9gCyD6L2dx8V77iHyLZ@68TL8sNaRpbFiRXAF6IucQ@rqt3Mmu1aoxXm7qH/tu6HJTljg35LglYr4T8rUdgaB/NqXtE8jy5hHo@cmOspQfhfV8/O5/VQOpguNcyud2XSSapkLCulcl6t3aJWE6f7QgZz9PAT2Zu8LQPvEpcr3SsyrRIi9vnRgpJbIxfCJp5PxM6O/zjGCZHUx74roBPuXMX@j/@SAzuAV@ly04CNCBaUz/dG13wfgGW@KNp0fV7Pc@LrjINFz5k39PXzOT206JfHlXBC2Lhj@5EMAr9TderNKVsc5j12kmkko8BPVTpCnBq0vwI3qkYM2LXAoxPI2m47O@5k81PJAj/YPB1DXqfRiC33tC@9eesttjXs5RiTwwI89vN4CLgev731yMN77M@RjsGQozInogksasaDMexWgN0YeNOu30eUULUiHMpPtr08EnW0AvaiCnyoENUfqRK1KpjfdYy7IjGn6Rh@2PWmqjJRtL02SQfvlcmHK0WT79kAP0vODpa7dw@V52vfSbNFuDiQXV0484QFyLPjHAQR@qkfHeJjo@DDpg/@5IUhTEYF2UMYCHPG4DPWivPfmxYXvw5a8Qv/nJ0O3Y0SR8pNECEW5s0q35JUZwgIn1uslbZ6rZCiQvXa/INpmNUbNR/Ur00Ecq2h5gd1u1DeKBTy4YaaDymUPXtGO5lZHpHywpANeQogPR9oVcgTkbWeD6t5p6bmu/XSBh@Bx0JBu8GA74lp3OSdmZl/hsBUxJtYWIeaTzRSh2UY9gz0kYbyZnHojG5UmclT@pEVoc/7hQLRYOQviIDvZuuswN1U68zke6dqliCZ/eHcjG8Zw6@/5uwt5OozNSrsl8pPD3Qmmxutl1dVpen0SsYv7dPL09N/1VqqkntxItubcnXDlHLmhvVt2zQ/f/6MnIFpTV1pN9XG9vZGtbi1s1E8KNpKsZpjgW3ZtqaWSlprMzxjT6pPnjxR7VNFqZSVs0/0y4D9p/jH//BZPNL1KX@TveYg9z9PNab@MpVyjSewk/LW04Mnn6WclLtoFPAx@LVQ2Ns70HV9iq9R2Jdyn2uAqbVns0KtWasZjca0obcbTSl3I@WmMylXkkkAG1KuPq295RM0X2YzFX55jUtNbzdHp6@PDs@OiqWanisdH74ols7ePc/ZeKosH6mzTI9vjw5fnrw7L5bEqD@@en/07hTvfd8fJd1usnmydXLQjQbtxsFBwQChB0ajDYqmPxUahXqapuzjxYbhxFLuZWP6ztRroOK1lHvLYfWWBuhvUq6Za6r7pf2SFVhXln1pX76JTpZ/Jyd470@tL1FsDayB3bVte2p576xr63pqDaMTu4umh3/WEE3f6k2tvhVaoW3fmufhv@FJ9OYkwlQRhqVTK6VZrR7u/ZOTN5isB8Rf8M@3LKJval3hzwps/vl0YWmWhA1hu7I1Km390uSupbLbbnpTP23LrKi0mkq7mjOTVssUtiyXYI7UPZtdXLw8PD@8uDBphzSt5QsHBf0An3qjUMtu@7lugyRm1CRFnXz48IG@HyZXE9HiDfHuw6Jz9YE38Ll6YOzthqo2K@2bGbaE2pOWUlUExarqISaqst2alnqMlWQea3ax0u0y8nl1q6I1GlsVPG/taLpqUe@m9smu1bKukhbFsjKVo1hhNzPxT72Z1VT@0eifptHL7NrQbtQaQABT0fizGAAwkKnkZjlypyHbrGhIzj1tc0vdKexm/@pPNUwql5UyJpWVnDSXct3OERFSzqi@le2SrJDUq1RoigLPCJACl3clGR9JQY6lVGmHBkeoZjWeVmtqWXAb1U49f5NzZlVJkmeyAMs@xI1S5TU/@UbOO3HTbgMmf9OZUZDAZ8PWuIevbFarG5uivb1TraJjI@ux0JM10eEljsutBY6JTw@mNKne8fp@KNXKDanWuJEQ0jpIUyZs20LKEgROzKJe76nk@KIL4Rn7GmztEy8IaINI2ekkioPuBBkTwWGvHjOH/o8D1muSePgMTx1v7HmT8XjiLT4v/GTP@fIFSRg5VIRYSzIoHJZKuzuVnd1yaae4s7uzWbG3KpWiXSra2zvbu1YRHnXH3tqp7NrFnc3d8ubm5i56K7vbUs4Lu37PNOG6bFlmvIFEjn65UaPfuETGoMGkXNfrUYXwyUjtak9y3cWL8Q6Tyzst60KW6CdNTIWCbmgRqixBxhX1VKs4hlFW9sc78ta2vLeBu7wvl9FkI5VZClQqKy1Z1pq77X15uyLvydvbslaVt@XqDOTM2VwQyrAYDYPhq@sS9YsIpcrbWBhKFWBVMeSfVsbEl3vYSMeUzXNwJLtbuzK9BkitUels7BVtvXggJmNbtpSbSV06BN7crZKXn9UaUl4hHpWylNPL0WaUy@fzCArnDbksnxg1M3P3DZO7@xa5f3K1hlQHDjLsnJxjU3/51xLgt9797/@ihGjPJd@iiv09/Lma2xsp5U2l3KrnhDext7Vco7RtJM51ri3eMXVzW2N44nZfsnO9Cf8svNg9n7bSWvM8uRry6Acydv7Q7ff90h/efP6GHZCiYBHaW9/1mvir4fLiRNAlb1VkDcafJJ8uPl0gIleYXKrIjBVMhn2U@a8lWPnu7tbOVk761TQf20Ghd5EA9jzkRuPhugzwMPbfOFSyChdZIBpvxtgqLFYBo2VAufWgcfsdXxq3XvH/84J3EtFFpqJSw4n7bpHX0dgG/Vap2dbYzbwGq1IvlQG1RdUw9tJxHDKrKqq7NIVfXTSBhRYWqxMAL/LB7at@3a4yv0aT4Y48McNAn/mIQp2atD/hVPhtrSqtlkM5JQ2MXqFlZXyhIMBngizBjzvsCrZF3@IR5A3p2MhVs9HaHYCm1QaM0rKUjM3fwgY2AupihiL73WzcGY@UWJvzxElYdmbvl6qYSRtpcViViO2NUVX6k@pqN5SqV78Pnz1zP42aw3ZVG9ZTuhcKw@pMulR9AbKR1od13a6OQGw1bRYKfrs@1P6kjjjxw7oFYOCmmRPtZqHpsJ6pK9GKX5uh/j1sF4@bYcFuF8fFjY/1r0WnbhWn@EJsxaD4C4Q3F6Wa1r8WwqpTw5d2DbckMaonBad6u0qNIZdqUP/adNp1S6sGGFgoHIMZ0Jk0g0KhrQF5gM77A6vBs2dOIWhMq4GuawT1qbx/3EzRaBfq9LynOrXp/tfmGOP3VNzrQBNoIB7jbusA84G@KmQs1LckXdA4JfKmIG9Yr2983N/4uFF/@vRrc6oP20Uh/j1rqXgifkrEr9qIuvFx1bC4SHiKoco/@Xs/GRsJk4uwPgi5OFoZKSjc@Iie0XI1zP4H)

Languages that are not on TIO:

- Reng (#19) [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~ (#48) [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish). Run like this: `deadfish.py < polyglot`. Prints a bunch of `>>` lines, but that's an unavoidable consequence of running any Deadfish~ program, so it's okay.
- Moorhens (#60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use python 2. Note that moorhens.py from master branch doesn't work.
- Morse (#73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c).
- Archway (#74) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98 (#76) [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Note that flags must be `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98. Could also be installed via pip.

Languages that use abstracted interpreters in the test driver:

- V (#2) [local](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)
- Alphuck (#44) [local](https://gitlab.com/PoroCYon/bfc/tree/master)
- What (#71) [local](https://github.com/gimmetehcodez/what/blob/master/what.c)

Other languages:

- Japt (#7) was updated in Tio to fix the parsing error we've been exploiting, so it must be tested individually [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Surface (#66) [local](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10116881/esoteric/Surface.zip). Tio Surface interpreter is no contest because it was created after challenge was started.

### Explanation

#### dash and the other shell scripting languages

The hard part about adding dash is that it has behaviour very similar to bash. So we needed a way where dash acted differently to the other shells. The difference in behaviour was found in the printf builtin. `a=$(printf \\x00)'` produces different results in dash then the other shells, assign a null byte to a in the other shells and the string '\x00' to a in dash. We then take the length of a and assign it to b with `b=${#a}` this gives a length of 4 in dash, 1 in zsh and 0 in ksh and bash. We then use this value along with the same trick we we were using to separate bash from ksh earlier (whether we realised we were using the same trick is a different matter, argv isn't special, at least as far as separating ksh and bash) in a case statement.

```
case $ar[1]${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;
```

Zsh gets separated with the first case, as b contain 1, Dash next because it has a 4 as the value of b, then bash, leaving the last case for ksh. We then exit.

Here is the code as it appears in the polyglot

```
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
```

#### Brain-Flak and Brainf-Flak classic

Because the code we needed contained a # the shell scripts had to be moved, this is why they are now just above the ruby block comment, and why it is across 2 lines. The `}` at the beginning of the second line of shell code is to close match the one on the previous line for Brain-Flak. It is inside quotes to not disturb the shell languages. There were also some `<>` added around the shell languages to switch stacks for Brain-flak. The braces in quotes inside the shell script case condition are to protect Brain-Flak classic from a `[]` See scripting language line for more information about changes.

#### Scripting languages line (python, etc)

The removal of the shell languages caused problems for a few languages. The brackets that were embedded in the shell languages had to be replaced for Brain-flak. The grass was moved to the front of the line to make prelude easier to work with. `li ha` was removed as it was no longer needed by moorhens. This line is seen as one big quoted command by the shells.

#### Ruby

The main trouble with the shell languages new position was given by ruby as it was neither in a block comment or a string (zsh doesn't like the =begin line) so we used the same string trick with ruby as we use for python on the scripting language line, open a string for both ruby and the shells with `'` then close it for the shells but not ruby with an escaped `'` then close it for ruby and open for the shells so we can insert `((((` to balance parentheses for Brain-Flak. We then open for the ruby and close the string for the shells so they can execute the case statement. The # near the end of the line acts as a comment for the shells but not ruby as it is inside a string from the perspective of ruby. We then close the string to ruby (with extra open parentheses for retina). Then we close the parentheses from earlier on the line for ruby.

#### Cubix, Prelude, Incident

Cubix had the usual need to be moved slightly.

A lot of spaces were added to satisfy prelude with the new position of the shell languages. Even more spaces were added to break Incident tokens. The dummy variable `ar` in the shell code is called so to detokenize ar, any other name is suitable for the variable otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

## 81. [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 100, 2254 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>){(<{}((x{}5){})>)}{}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'@*99.?.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
<3>
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004241 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2338 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLc9tIkj4bsf9gLmWQbQAk8SJFvfiQZFuadXd7pLVke6JJWoZAUIQFAmwAFCnLdOx1N/Yw97nscf7HXPdXzB/p/bIKfEikZHfEbMRCJlCoyqrKV2VmZcEXTtL/7bccXewkCm4ugyhlqZekrBv7115ssOc3bN/xk2q5IkkcKo66I9cPL1na95gfDkcp6/mBl0iuk7ImG2ajGFRgORZ7TleASb0oZtSFDa4C5jN3OGQXgdM3XBb4gD2ytgGfRAOCSb14GHu4Jyz0vC5Lhp7r93yXz8W8SeqFiR@FicF894qN/SBgXS9AhwUCbgmDsVGyVCWmM6RuJDFc7vAeuvO3vAeY0JuR7A2dmJMcsSGnf0b5OHaGQyAp5dgpEE/9gZcwP1US5jmJT3xEl8QLu5xbwzmHI@aEy1Sya99hDvAdxXzsxItTkGfwcVnfiz0M6dDkl7EzYOo49lOwgJh5wE48J2ZnsedpmAVC8BLXGQKPO1NisohmSIkQgwurXlcOj48UCE30MJxhKuXiytm//Sg5zGiw/HkNv4Ys16TDP71kt/k2lYEFBoNgh7HqaKzxlSVmu@3hN7EvzMt4KmFUCVwJmBkNUxMjO3EK9BYl/bpsDIOlaVn9niSWFElAdSEL9ipk70qcLncUxx6wWLDUuQLJQRRegpsgNR6FxI2QbVoQgBuF3aTEvGvwLAqFhKIx5@9Z34fIEhKIcwH2OC5xXiwCzk4sA2hexs/ZvEkUjDgceiYpqR94gq404qsee8d6jh9QF7TTUALr2EtGQUp9RmGX5D7wQ69rsBkabtQloEF0jekcDMorsG4GS6uNIwVgiCHipFLTP/7y1@7lJcY5cN0o7mbK@o51I3c0AMIOR9aBIpK6RqETcLQAV6LZRXdMcO0EftdJafrwJpuCI8FnHUejoMsiTBiPfSysvnONxdjreW7qCRWPRilwLLGBcyVshC/0FoQPnAsIlk/A5@Zk62z/BaTkekJh9MEo7W0zfXjIlMT8oO7tqntP2x5w0wytkDfNyxq0zSjwKrwpjynOu4OFPEl7zvyIVlEw7I9gM9ASJkNYk5iY6TogJyGjksLuldgFZzS3RFB0vkTHnhJ77ALrekYY1xGhA9Rfp3WbjbCQ6Qzurop53SUNg3ZCydJkxUgE0RgTc9zIeEKnQ5rcuXQwVZoRdCAIEjPymrukXYXQdBrtwmPb@oUP6ZAewNRkwliiEeCVsoDBaEJ6S4ti4NxgFFeY6IUkmd@DkAfQ2/iGuR4tBqwKT9g5mmTEFSPxoUdRj1l6uVr9hvDT2DzQfzEd/bP5qIyJ@HtiPmA9b8wCJ7wcOZdQ5ChEF8d1vWGarSBQkqRYI/fNIK/UM5tuJH0pv39/bm7bMmu/NAdZHyG9zEI7pPZg1ACs1gOscubEl3wlsq4fY70EN/dnB8D1vcnljwRyB4GP8gMozBwTlMybeO4oxXKDIo/7vtuH7hJ2oViwwjrenx5Vy7PD5Oi9@dSEjN18VpYMc15FaDw4hE4SXR0HVp@Gat6p4MJfrnh8ZCcZrBk4mqMIC7VUa5iOAd3LmAZvfkqRBMzfzHXzlTUPL@b8BIN/JMcUe7@OIDDos38ZEogTzt3@kmX0k1CBq/ATH1wnB066fvbqmPzBe0/EMOC78GXLxjxCRIPumYOmhpkQJM/tR0wPmZLhoMrcn34CWmYSu7ygLwURsmaATyrxizfNBvokYrP7DpU1V@H4lEqJtWS5U4IPCxKoUDgKAryMQr7EVE@7ha65XpIYWDDgrUHRCLCTi542vQuY9uNozLypVlPWTfc7BfJidOFP/h9KxCW8xB1ULYmBV32PHFYAZ4KQ5Yx1KxCcdy@iAdl59p5TTPg@j@EbevAH0vAm7cPS6S6TnUY09IDSHUuiAE8E56pW4wGdohifIj9Ub5WnT58qu0pTKaG0h1KdSntUKqK0x0s6LxGcQSXeo8RL1NriPaiuo0xbs5EnWodEO6Go9bM/VJ3W7m6lU3JadvYs01ODM4HvALROD4yjaI0GFTVNbo5BqHHRkwT5ZxDOzwj52M8@eeIeAsTFxkGaT9aWZMGMyl1bKi9ayiJWfWcOwD5jeLM@ipCXh@IdXvvhVUQ6ag5mpXPLsKt3hsB@Z7Vnz0/6/HYHdAWt1RbeOxlc9PhtDcBuFgYgpqA9EvGFmzKKRKIImj/mYIMojAQq4JcfOuYb/jDgPdbhc9dI30HmuYc1f@npOxXzwg/NC6/3EOTR8@evOEzv4sJ/CAhMIbxnzzVg8ehiHc8Qm/VXnDi7w/WzUZwGetdM6en9z793wf1V2fSdmwTR/NW8cA6mkZz03oOiyrrSC7@tF@unUYCd3jfGcB2K4J1gXlg/1i5740H3IdaQb/CAaRDAnoBlsHOryo11EYy63uy5flDOw7uxgOgd@gMdmr1pWFyAeKX4hlufB0a5F9CIYWjjEweR0zXFVtT3FhIVvPcmzmUU3phLns2IL74D1VnMwRZ7z7Q/SkfiThvOb8nOH9LvsQWZQVrVg@f2YfZ4AB5IbD6ku2LZkKnWjwLnyryg4nkPxfWkCmJi/xK729nzIbD3p0PH9cxxQo8H7Uc4SoZckLz0EBiixzgQ94dA/NCFZw0XhYcAQWLAb79H67gSuE4A1asIxaN8j77EI/8eVwPn4ob8Wf/3KxDNelksMh02pOEWi1aF6dFiQ7bILA2HD/d33az/zs763iIJxQdwI@ydvW85JXgWfwAWlLtLxQeVxI/0xf4vEZpF8cA6Y@RcO4gPAieBrqQZx71rSIjfHtNdchnuKHDiRekxzb2H1GwP/tA2btFz6LsRnLtQVXoJ/LXaGlLcdz9GWgxDCUZ@W3Slt8yMvkQYRJ7466O2NHJT2j09oEbfYZ7ExoW2hkt6YUQPMc2NxvR7cAX3o2tP3Ne7pc9rsfoO86MHXCUQfK9277rf0tb3fgLjg9t6s3i1FqvUDdbW77LXURRj55qwsmE9Kp61ynxqvDJ@No6NU3bqB1HyKD@wb08ScV@vygvQi9h3Qt0lHV4ur@@2FjHu4tgBvz8gYCe4jILN7UvTwe1BLRjFPbL22fN7jdzcSNn2N43UPKyJQjt7Pmjir/DvWwpCWRHYdJ/im3lxvbJ8w6Jlm4GHycQOgHquJ/HI2p7rWJx4a5ULc2cwB7HbHzs3j6rgt/zJQ8ye@ZNdyuLzUPpRZL45zcbj03S/z16tDLv1@LB3hPxT4MFgX9F9RbSsbNm/s4dtWdSDb/re8Mz@PNWWlLIDCdT5cZaATuZnPLlXoRt7PPE2SyWwHKUDRwM4rTSKDcbhVNUpFjVNEp3I/F2GAJtB8Tw7pTpFCj9h8EMph8V2tdVi@dvJrrVrT1mDybsy63TEqDzpdjgZ8gT5G9G1lXc6jbyi60peaYe7zFI4qBdAB9eCOnfgej5/CDwXpLPQGfDsKpVnlNZEChdOgvL2fSfsIlp/G/o8S@JGsUhEimw33xn9/W/d7Djj0gORAz9xAjCCDuCigdePxnti3mz2g@HQoeMQGgNBYiDyKPqLA5aM/dTti1MM@LC3R2fbWQo6OxDEywmF6UtYCKGiqQccnFQITWDTjTyxILKJ571mRCEwGA1CNva7aT8xYO1D1@Mp7lnaFZjEBBamcUQLqsResa5HEStPA30aQbZBFF3x7BNh8ve/icQ7Gn1SISrPpucnQUszMjgGm2e7XTcaAevZIJ@9OMpAVGIywpsROHKD5eyJeo25fYefCEAT9Vk@nKYROfEXB6dMP2QKnWNSerzm99T8wZs/vmtZncZXNjCxiTUpI8f5Jv@gb9mJXGIzkNqU9Gq52ULzolVhcn4iZ2TRmRk/IporlVhNTKUyF9csvz3gx21c77wxz2/zQ4yQojc6xwoTrA@8anxosWgaeRW734GfMv00ZVU67PXAEpTEAR2j41PK1VKX/IR9YX3SFd1ldtXCm2BIQMcDg8Yi57Cc9DFfehcjvjm6LhvlSoOTkz9v1Ju8FHvdiA6QWh/a446ZzLjSbk9@sMoTsC2KAf7MpJVz@KeXt3mjaX35ksDsy/JUqfGkHC3v/O3Jq5PD07ODs7enYONUUJk7iuKBszARpATDAF65HwX8RA78iH0v@bbZeMLthvQkA1RVlndYHVaQwUI9mRuWjK2yLudFUbRxSzJvu9eYmY@ezzJTx064tDPBKsmymSvNFICYhzU5gl2dIQ/FuV1jrjg5MmuAIB0EcfA5wvO3dYTdbeXwguF79A6mZ2QsQ3FSF1DrgYhWAZzhLWAEkmuJmP6TMB/Cj3wbc4L6FuYAlr41@9LERwevfn775nB17qVpM5gVkLmGLH0CcThBHAU72OMaTgdtM72JsoPSmWGA3e@L7L0TLExbMk/Ekyb1yDAHWNu0KHiaIqHFzciOGOwgSGBIu11YhoublAwLLKrIvc8T8HIODDDmfq7EZIlgk8bqgRkMxxjRrvtRdM5zOD5ysu7Mue2Z//jLX8U5cztF@T@ycg/l/xLlDyYxaPVgUuA4Zw2x5d2rE5bAWwnCB85kiSZyGOSQ/HCEgG8ADl5zhhC4QHZB72IctfUO/IQQwEyyfGTs@Hxe3FH7aTrcNU3y79g89AyevPQmkANspYFw2/x1RMf@sM/mZnVzwzaBpH49G5CfJl1SJk0MqGm7UCHp2h82Pl64rF6vMzlxncBrbNYEI82886Eif5wjmgesJEKBFkMfdFn0QFsz66bmnaKtUVdahYqtsE4NXl7IBY5C5QWAaFQdZvyQ4YmijFV0MOVNUm5Ub2YhDuKLMGID4hP/@GM2kI6BxNiaLK3oLvBFC0@X@XdiS2NZDPJ7AuPJtV15neowaMh/r9GcEOX/FOVW29K/dtZ9uDDXnYPV7xPU@18XEC1s/zSMKIN6BFyZWjbLFdPe1JbWiZwNBWxpVXzBkFgHWFeu53@KhsnBi8NXPx6fnK6cr3NI5T6YwpRmvdjWjVKrMy8o93R@xtLnR@bp6@dHM0YuY5U13cdq3eD3EXtgsvciP7k6FW9Ymci2vnfgRYpkLSGLBMoS4AuRO1mZVdVup61OvdkOcyvTf1n38UvOKND3Lii1E/7pi8LWGJhXs6zrWXQF9XjkVF9PCcL/vHy@P8vZ0uF5uWl2vWuTTnslY5HNlfNq/Q62mvgCQfBgNj3sRFaTx96uyRZzudJKImwZEZGLiOaY3Ok5ZzbRfCx2dvwDHidEUB/7roBOuHEV@z/@tQl2AK/SxaYBGxEsKJ/vjW74PgDLfJ5Y6vo85@jENxkF85ZTb@DrZzN8aNEvjlRhhKI4xfYj6Qf@Rc1ptCZsfuD42GmrkQwDP1XpmHNi0P4K1KgaEWDXA49OSes7nexIls1OTov88PVkBH6dREO22NO@9GalN9jWsJcjDA4N8NiPowHgevzxxiML77E/RTo6g4/KDIkWZlEzGoxBt4rZjb436fqX8BKqVoJB@cG2F8e2jlbEXlSBDRWs@iNly5YZ87uOmpc45rQcww@73kRVxoq22yHuoF4Zv79WNHlFB/h5d3b43b1/8D1b@06aLcL5ofHywpkFLJg8O3KCE6HPEelDA2wUfOj0/k9eGEJlVKA9gIIwZwQ6Y600@ya2NP@Cacku/Gt2gnXfSxwqt0EEX5g3a3xLUpvCIXxss3ba7rVD8gq1G/MPpmHWbtV80Lgx4ci1pprvN@xipVAs5sOCmg/JlT17RjuZaR6e8tyQDXkCID0faDXwE561kQ9reaeu5ruNcoH3wGuxqN2iw9fENG7zztTMP4NjKqEmFtqh5hONxGEZhj0FfiShvFkaOMNbVWbyhD4Eo@nzfrFIOBj5c0Lgq9k@LXIz1T41@d6plgVI5uVgpsZ3lOG333L2JmL1qRoV98qVp/s6k81C@@V1TWk5vbLxa@fk6uTkz1pbVXIvjmV7Q64VTClnFqwvW6b58eNHxAxMa@lKp6U2t7YKtdLmdqG0X7KVUi3HAtuybU0tl7X2RnjKntSePHmi2ieKUq0opx/o64W9p/jj/3DNX@n@lNdk1Rxk9XqqMfXXiZRrPoGeVDaf7j/5KOWk3HmziMvg92Jxd3df1/UJfkZxT8p9rAOm3plOi/VWvW40m5Om3mm2pNytlJtMpVxZJgYUpFxjUn/DB2i9zEYq/vozbnW90xqe/Hx4cHpYKtf1XPno4EWpfPr2ec7GW3XxSo0Ven1zePDy@O1ZqSx6/fHVu8O3J6j3fX@YdLvJxvHm8X436nea@/tFA4juG80OMJr8UGwWG2masl/OC4YTS7mXzclbU68Di5@l3BsOq7c1QH@Rcq1cS90r75WtwLq27Cv76nV0vPh3fIx6f2J9imKrb/Xtrm3bE8t7a91YNxNrEB3bXRQ9/FkDFH2rN7EurdAKbfvOOA//GxxHr48jDBWhWzqxUhrV6uF5eXz8GoP1MPEn/PmWRfhNrGv8swKbXx/OLc2SsCHsVDeH5c1fW9y0VHc6LW/ipx2ZlZR2S@nUcmbSbptCl@Uy1JGap9Pz85cHZwfn5ybtkCb1fHG/qO/jajSL9eyxl@s2iWNGXVLU8fv37@n3fnw9FiVeEHXv543LL7yA6/qBvncLqmoUVv@27R2jiEJxv1Xt3E41hr8nbaWmCIJU1YPLVGW7PSn3WFnmnmgHdsCuINpXN6tas7lZxfvmtqarFrVuaB/sej1rKmtRLCsTOYoVdjsVf@rttK7yS6M/TaPK7N7UbtU6QNTJ7bSq8QrRA3CggsL3/6N/UYK9JlNy0xyZ85BtVDVsDjxtY1PdLu5kf42nGtCWK0oFaMuKo@wXdnaMvXWMpT8lJ83UoGHniA9Szqi9ke2yrJBa1CgTFgWeESBGr@xIMi5JQRCo1GgLCUutZkmodntiWbBrtYtG/jbnTGuSJE9lAZZdxFClxpOS8q2cd@KW3QFM/vZiSl4MV8HWuAuqbtRqhQ1R3tqu1dBQyFostGRFNHiJ43J1huXkw4NqTWpceJd@KNUrTanevJXgcy/AwDHbshBTBYETs6jXeyrqETxg1@XBeXpBQNtXip3HURx0x4jnnkq5xMM1OHG8keeNR6OxN79e@Mmu8@kTYsIhGXi4fEsyyD2Xyzvb1e2dSnm7tL2zvVG1N6vVkl0u2VvbWztWCRZ@297cru7Ype2NncrGxsYOWqs7W1LOC7t@zzRhSm1ZZryAwJK@dqnTd0GR0W8yKdf1epSxfBKoXe1JrjuvGG0zubLdttqWLNF3YEyFQG7JKqgsQQgY9VSrNMI6qO6NtuXNLXm3gKe8J1dQZIHKLAUilJW2LGutnc6evFXFULtwOrryzN5j8taOvCtvbaFSq02B3YzqOd4MtsIwGH66LlG7cKCqvIWVqdQAVhNd/mWpT3y1i31@TJsNDo5YfHNHpmqA1JvVi8JuydZL@2IwtmlLuanUpXP0jZ0aOaFpvSnlFaJYqUg5vRJtRLl8Pg@fddaUK/KxUTczb9Q0uTdqk3ciT2BIDcxBap2TczeTpastwGmqXPIlqtpfwx9rud2hUtlQKu1GThgfe0vLNctbRuLc5DqijqkbWxrDG1fSsp3rjfk1t4krFnKptOZ9fD3gvhRobP@he3npl//w@uMX7KcUBSvG3vyq18W/Om4vjgVe8mZV1nIJrg/nH87h36tMLldlxoomw67M/HMZOrqzs7m9mZN@M83H9mNonYeTPQ@R1miwLp48iP3XDiXAwnlMicLrETYecx1mpMQUqfebd@u4Yt@p4v/LB3US4UWSVangxJduiWflWIG@zmp1NHY7y@iq1EpJRW2eg4y9dBSHzKqJXDEN4dfmRcxCq4I1CICnDOEmVL9h15hfp8HwRNSZzUDXrEexQUXa7XAs/I5Wk5aTqxyTJnov4bLUv1gU4FOBlqDHHXQF2aJt/gr0BnQI5apZb@0eQMvqAEZpW0pG5veQgW2FOh@hxH43Gff6I8DWZjRxFBaNWf1CFFOpkJYGNYnILgxr0k@qq91S4F/7Onj2zP0wbA06NW3QSOlZLA5qU@lK9QVIIW0MGrpdGwLZWtoqFv1OY6D9pA458oOGBWDMTSMn2u1c0mEjE1eilT63Qv1r2CkdtcKi3SmNSoVfGp9LTsMqTfAD20pB6Vcwb8ZKNW18LoY1p44f7UHucGLYSIpO7W7OG12u1KDxueV0GpZWC9CxWDwCMcAzaQXFYkfD5AEaVzvWgmfPnGLQnNQCXdcI6kNl76iVotApNuh9V3Xqk73PrRH676p4NjBNoAF59LsrA4wH/GrgsRDfAnWB44TQmwC9QaNR@GWv8Euh8fTp59ZEH3RKgv271kLwhPyEkF/WEbXwy7JicZbweECVf/B3fzAKCZNL0D4wuTRc6ikwLPyCluFiNUz/Fw)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.

## Explanation

All my changes are at the end of line 19.

To quote @WheatWizard: "Klein is a group of 12 languages that are embedded in different topological surfaces." Klein 100 is embedded on some topological surface (WheatWizard says it's a sphere; he made Klein so I trust him). In 100, when the ip is deflected off the north end of the program by the `/` on the first line, it will appear on the east edge, on the tail end of the 19th line (opposite of where Klein 201 reappears). I used a combo of `*` and `?` to toss the extra items on the stack, and `@*99` (running from right to left) puts 81 on the stack and exits the program.

#### Underload

`*` concatenates two stack items in Underload. If there aren't two items on the stack, it causes a crash. I had one too many `*`'s, so I swapped one for a `?`. If we need more `*`s later in the program, we should be able to swap out any of them for `?` without issues.

Note that `?` pops an item from the stack, then skips the next command if the popped item is nonzero. Since we're popping a lot of nonzeros, `?`'s will need padding commands if we replace `*` with them. This doesn't apply for the one I used because the last item left on the stack is a 0 (because I multiplied the last remaining item with an implicit 0).

#### Retina

Retina did not like the "nested quantifiers" caused by the long string of `*`s and `?`s.  Prepending each of these with a `.` settled that issue.

#### zsh

zsh didn't like my changes, so I wrapped them in a new set of single quotes. Problem solved.

#### Incident

My new single quotes tokenized `''`, adding a space tokenized `'`, putting an x between them tokenized `"'x`, so I settled on separating them with an `a`.

Comment: Klein 100 is embedded on a sphere btw.

Comment: `+` instead of `*` might give less problems with Underload. Or `?:`, which would *grow* the Underload stack.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Growing Underload's stack is fine, but I'm not sure if the colons would break anything. '+' lead to a mess with Incident, and trying to fix that made complications with evil and alphuck.

Answer (score 5):

## 96. [EmojiCoder](http://esolangs.org/wiki/EmojiCoder), 2823 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbcttIds9G5Q/2pQVyDIAkbqQo8S5pbGnXs@ORYvmSMknLINgkYeHCAUCRMk3XPqUqyT5stvKQ2q1kklSlah/yF/u6X7FfsH8wOacbICmRkjyVpCqwCDTQp7vPrc@lu92zotGPP2bwImeBez10g5jENIpJP3SuaKiRr6/JoeVE5WJJEBhUGPQntuMPSTyixPHHk5gMHJdGgm3FpEXGSS8aFkiGhNTqczBhEIQEmxDv0iUOscdj0nOtkWYT1wHYE6NCqBd8cKBVFHgIGdNwHFK4R8SntE@iMbWdgWOzEQmdxdSPnMCPNOLYl2TquC7pUxcarNCwC9AZmURrn/igmtAPBAKXPb6F9PItSwHGpynhdGyFjPCAjBkXUvqnoTUeA5JChpwD4rHj0Yg4sRQRakUOchOaRNTvM56Nl3wOiOWvU0muHItYgO8kZH1HNIyBPI31S0Y0pNClhYMPQ8sj8jR0YmABsvSInFErJC9DShUYBURBI9saAx43hoTBAhwhRkI0JrJGQzo@PZFAdLyFZo1jIROWXv71N4JFtCbJXtTh1xTFunD83VMyz3awDFhAZyDecShbCml@JpHe6VD4zcyePgwXAvQqAFdcogfjWLfUMSCoxoCgbmERS@pVURu7awOTxi1ZrCkUh@qDNMgzn7wuMMrsSRhSwGPFVOsSiHYDfwj8BGLDiY/88MmeASKwA78fFQi9Aq4FPpdRMGUcfjlyQGgRisTqAYMsG3nPJwNjKEwH0L2Eo@m4UeBOGBy0jGJUQOAKNMUenw3IazKwHBebQD12xbEOaTRxY2wz8fsoec/xaV8jKRp20EcgL7iC4SzolH2A@eOtzTqGFACDIAJGKlb9@Te/7w@H0M@RbQdhP1HX16Qf2BMPELYYshaoIips4FsuQwvgCjg6bw4DXFmu07diHN6/ToZgSLBRp8HE7ZMABgynDkytkXUF03EwoHZMuZIHkxhwLBDPuuS2wuGaC4R7Vg8EywZgYzOyVXL4BKRkU64yqjeJBxWijo@JFOnv5IOafLDToYCboim5rK4P66BvWo59gjfpPsV5fbSSJ2rPSyfAeeSORxOwGlDjR2OwJyEy07aAnAjNSgz2r0B6jNHMFoGqs0k6pVJISQ9mdkoY0xGuA9hexZmb9LCSaQp3U8Vof03DQDtByeJow0y4wRQGZrihEQWd9nFwa2jBUHFC0BEniI/Ivtwk7dIHTcfeepRU1J4D0kE9AGOTCGONRgAvFTkM9MaltzYpPOsaerG5kV5JkjgDELIHehteE5viZIBZQbmlw0EmTDEiB/QoGBBDLZbLDwg/DvUj9S1Yj4/6vTJG4m@J@YgM6JS4lj@cWENQ5MCHJpZt03GczCCgJIphjtw2hOyjmlh1LRoJ2cPbYzPrltj7tTHQ@nDpJTbaQrUHRnnAatWFWU6scMhmIuk7IcwX9/r26ABwdWtw8T2C3EDgvXgHCqlrAiWjM2pPYphuoMjTkWOPQHcRO59PWG4dbw8Pn9ZHB5OjDpZDIzJm63FR0PTlJ0Tjzi5UlOhmP2D1savWjQ9M@Osf7u/ZirwtHQdLFMFCrX3VdEsD3UuYBv78HGMJMH@p82YzaxlgLPkJDP4GHVNIv5@AwECfnaGPIJa/dPxrltGJfAlchRM5wHV04ajrL5@doj94Q3kUA3znvmzdmAcQ00DzxEVjRSoEgdqjgKg@kRIcZJF51A@Alh6FNiuoa2GEqGjAJxn5xarSjj7wGO22QyWtTTg2pFQgbVHsFsCHuRGokD9xXXiZ@GyKyVSZg67ZNIo0mDDAWw3jEcBOzFNlcRMwHoXBlNCFUpe2DfcTBfJk0nNm/w8lYiNe/A5UrYmBffoSOWwApoIQxYR1GxCMd08CD@08ecMoRny/DsE3DMAfCOPreASWTrWJaDWDMQWUblgSCfCEIF1W6iykkyTtQ@D48lza2dmRalJLKkDpAEoNLB1gKQ@lA1ZSWQnhNCyxFgVWwto2a4HfutKinfY8U7oo2hnGrR@dsWy1a7VSt2C1zeRZxKcCzgR8B0Cr@IB@JKXZxKKiiK0pEKr1BgIn/yUI51sI@ci3DnriAQSIq9RBWA7WEUTOjNJNWyquaoo8Wr3SPWCfNr7eHkWI612xBhDAXQaoo6vShaGZ5RtdQN6z2XLgRCN2uwG6gdZmDWsdeb0Bu20BqCVhAMQUmCUhX5gpw0gkCEDzpwzMC/yAowL8cnxLf8EeGniPbfjcNNI3kOlRmPNDqvccH8sPgKnVCoMc9HrOXaDAF0Q9fW4BCye9bWyD8Gy04cfJDcbHkzB2aT95/ulXfRDApnhG1nUEAf3lsnABfENRqYM7pZU0xRd22y7ZDxMX0r0H@rAtDOItd1nY3leNvKCg/iBZn2V5gKkLtGGEA6ZuU79hariTPk2f2ztlPLwZDvDWvuMxycETYxtmee5ofiuY4e0x6QndwOrrPBF16EqUnOl0Zg0D/1pf82pa2PsCHNN4g6wyz3g0iSf8jsnmQ0Jzxvi7bzImkEbZ6plUDyKr59zBQURi7y6l5XMBzbQ6cK1LXrzA4nZSOTGhM4TMNn3eBQbRHgTkY8um@pQ97rQf/iQaM2Gy0j39hS6/3wXi@DZ4Vn9VuAsQyHTZ7aeoHFMEG@YBooqLPeoai5xbTHWt3jW6stFP1x8ccJjPExVsR9PO540SUYNVLrZaVhqP725v20n7anV7a74CxTqwA0ib6UP@CJyK41muWuyvFe@0r6nrX5W2mR/ryoKgwLUiUJA4YTO9ArGw231Ki37CnrhWuCrdo7IrdNKU@66sbdVm7NiB6ySamb5sGcDHMO92SLTqBtcV2W3VFN8Sk/kUoh50vJ/vtZuBHWOydIfqfIFF4nkKZoJruqAFd7HLDqb4u3PCjoIryu/bXdDHrVh9gcVRXaYMEGtvNu/bD2korgOx23ZLeLkVq9h2t36vkedBEEKiGpGiZtwrnq1qHDluEJFzdr@PF5CiRxG/b1fgdbY5lq/aIz6tluXtzbYixTwaOWL3O4RrucPA3asMdQtud2rAJBygYU@eX2rUlkbJNB80SsvwJfDN5HmnNb@Ev4eUAxdAwHw7GMcsi9sV5U4LlkT8dxMIYT4ueG0n7sSoLDUrjOi9KlUjR6E9mlrX90I95DnuYnPqOWq4WM8C4f/ZMLv3D9P/Miu10e3@/d3eEO@lS8FMs/uGUEnRMH9iC9MwvtxmDdwJndCtNuS094GC4nxxUHwvUkZCRo18vHTv7fOL0EYvjm/32hzLdWCePxjD1MgZBNFnwQMJwNCfjG/Icj17mPgvHpgTT4Kg/9M1dWl1Kg@HQjVyTuMHsDj2AkhOAw9CAv8LJJuE6mxbkd9vSJZ9WfX8wXkC8UR4X79sueEF21NaLvJGhWQzDL45YbL1ES33FzPPfDukbMk3XcQiGVyInngQOcVBqBEGJ8tWPq8oAm@EnnjoA1gKxXZ4cJGdbx5FBEKimME6A9Juk@x8VjNq5oI0iVgTSbfLe2XLvcezMduaecGbtrNWt5mVVFXKSh2/RgyJgVIXDONWUOsG3MBhD47ninTiWx5b18dySmmdbx5AvII7RiPL70Ou@Mp32PqcHYR8CZzvs7zERPyPf@gnG2lDCkR6TgSzYOjj5m/g0VEwPeDjJqMfjccWbsRhH5CeuHwFT31yRKKpE9sjvn8G4dSrk5eVZPMj2ZKGlzNMEtew4EKFqgHgYMVcaBybfkC5ViQDL1ulREGMOvF8MnX68SjSIPjwbco2V9IFf8AkRDA/DgPUqgJ5RvoUcyW2APlhArJ1g@CSrXsiJn/8A9/ygUoHVQjL6fBsD3JtRAI2w2T7LLYdTADrtJOPNAwSEBmZDJH2BDhyDTpN@XeF2COL7UWBJqrpTgwOw3djnhydE/WYSLiHjhszdWcgZ49e/Px12@g2PxNPp3/6lY5rwYxv4lfqvhmJBZKC1BeoV@vVBlSvaiUiZmdiQhbu1rLNyaVS8dlEZCwzcaU7Kx7b6GV6R6dsZ4Vtn/mYSOAOqh/B/IBXhXXNJ00zK09cx3Niop7HpIwHDcDiWFDiW8MEt@5xlwCbZGfkExmhrqg2McsGvHGGuLgx5TW/TpexSuvLjfpT2puw1PyqqBVLTUZO9qLZaLFSSPsBbl2233WmXT1KudLpzL4yijNgWxAC@GMdZ87xd0/nWa1lfPoUQSwiigupzpaDcXpn52fPzo7PXx69fHUObFxwKjMnQehZKxOBSjB2IUgcBS7bCwZ@hA6NHjYbj5jdEB4lgLJMshZpgGsmYKEeLQ1LwlZRFbO8yOuYJVnW3apMzMfAIYmpI2dM2olgpWjdzBVSBUDmwZycgF1NkQfFmW8xV4wckTSBIBUIYuBLhJdv2wi7WcvgOcMP8B2YnpCxDsVIXUFtB0JaOXCCN4fhSG4lYvG/hPkY/MjDmCPUQ5gDsPDQ6GsDnxw9@/bVi@PNsdeGTWA2QJYasnb85ngGwT3YwQHTcNziTfUmSLboU8MAdn/E940sd2XaouUWEGrSAA2zC3MbJwVbIItwchO0Ixo5ciMwpP0@WIbedYyGBSwq3/VZbv2IGWCAtvRzBSIKCBs1N7dqwXBMIQyy3/PGWQbHeo62nXboUP3Pv/k9P@HQiaH8d0l5AOVf8/I7HRm0uSXOcVyyBtny@tkZicBbccI9a7ZGEzoMdEiODyG04wEHrxhDEJwju6J31Y/cfg38BCEAM9HyobFj49GwK4/ieFzTdfTvkMsONLZmTmcgB7CVGmR/@vcTPHAC9lnfK@/tmjogqV6lHbJ9zCGu4/IOFaUGKiRcOePm@55NGo0GESPbcmlzr84ZqWetdyXx/RLRLMAKPBRoE2gDTVYtoK6VNJOzVt5UsCnOQsmUSLcOXp7LBRyFzAoAouBnP@GHCJ4oSFiFW6J0FjOjep2GOBBf@AHxkE/s2FHakQod8b4VUdjQ3dV6Le5TrWmzti4G8Q2CnSNYTdymOgQ05N@2aI4P5b/n5XbHUD93tx2ZWerO0ebJGPn2uRakhRye@wGu358ArkQu6sWSbu4pa/NETLoCbHFWfIIuYR7AvLKp8yEYR0dPjp99c3p2vnGyg0FKt8EkIrUa@Y6qFdrdZUG6pfMpS78@0c@ff32SMnIdq6TqNlbbOr@N2B2DveEr45tDsYqNgUzjSztm27jqCcsUtxCyrNXXAJ/wZbyNUWVlvmh3G62On9kY/tO2Y1cZLYcnraDUidihK4lsMTDP0vX@l8ElqMc950nUGCGcj@snS9LdAjy2UWzpfXql4zkDQVvtI4hZuXEDW4WffeE8SIcHO5F8yUKm3iKrsWxhY012HRGepAZLTG60XDIbaT7lmR07Omb5ENSHjs2hI2Zcef7HzjlBBvAsXiUNkIjgSgTLja5ZHgDTfLnG2XfY8rcVXicULGvOqeeoL1N8cNKvNvPBCAVhDOlHNHKdXt1qtmdkudV93z6/Fo1dJ5Zxg32mYX4F1MgKEmA2XIr7841qNzkMQNI9@zzb9j@bAL/OgjFZ5bRPaVp6AWkNeTqBzkEDKPlm4gHcgD1eULTwlHwXqNAY@CilSLRhFDmhQfP6ZRhdG9FZ3xmCl5CVAhiUr0xzdWDAUvKQi0pgQzmrfo6Lt@uM@UmHHNY4ZrUtzfH7dCZLU0mpdZE78F2avrmSFHFDB9hJi@TYRf/2kYt07ltxMgmXxxXWJ04asMDgyYYnOBE8CItHXCBRcECnD39JfR9URga0PVAQYk2AzlAppKeyC8uzc2t24RfJ/ultL3Eszd0AfGFWr7OUpL4Ah/C@QzpxZ9Dx0SvUr/Wf6Zpen8tZt3mtgyNXWnJ21DTzpVw@n/VzctZHV/b4MWYyiyx4ygtN1MQZAKlZV6kDP8GzNrN@PWs15Gy/WcyxFvCazytzaPA50rV51lro2cfgmArwJeTaIWcjBcVhaJq5APxQQlm94FnjuSwScYZHEHH4rJPPIw5a9gIR@Kx3zvPMTHXOdZY71ZMASR96qRrfUIYff8yYexCrH@yV5OCgWNrJZUjmUNRznadv3z65qktta1DUvu@eXZ6d/Y3SkaXMk1PR3BXrJKcLGT1nfNrX9ffv30PoQNotraV1lbYqddtya38/Vy/sVXKFw4IpFeoZ4pqGaSpysaicd3b9uuM446jfh18wwjNK4DxrKJpHcMnmmSSVS9L5Ozxbc7AD/9gfXMtXvO@wL8lnBrJ57ShE/n4mZFqPQJdKezuHjwBVmmdXrXZIhMxnIXMtZN433gsZiJAyrVZ3scg32o2G1mrNWmq31RYycyEzWwiZooisyQmZ5qzxgnXRftrifeW/BzZ/C8@G2m2Pz749Pjo/LhQbaqZ4cvSkUDx/9XXGhLfy6hUrS/j64vjo6emrl4Uib/XzZ6@PX53B96jbOjzMa6qqHmqtLmAx@yrfyjfjOCZvL3IwN562Zq90tQGDfitkXjBItQNodBSA/yRk2pm2fFDcPd07PTwoGq5xZZiX5uXz4HT5R56fnkKFMzM@BKExMkZm3zTNmUFfGdfG9czwglOzD0UK/wwPio4xmBlDwzd801zv6J4/7zR4fhpAVwE0i2dGjL0aA3gOT0@fQ2cDGPgD/HMMAxGcGVfwZ7gmu95dQF5ldDpCG9S0W94bF/e@bzO7U65223TmxF2RFKROW@rWM3rU6ehc0cUiaClWLxYXF0@PXh5dXOiYPs0a2fxhXj2Eq9nKN5LHQabfQv5pjZ2OIMnTN2/e4O/N9GrKS6zwZkreJBe86eJ@RQyCwwT0zer5ZgrX1R2d3CyQG5cst8vd@UJRlEcdqS5xSmSZgiOVRbMzKw5IUWT@qQrWwSxBDiDvlZVWa68M73sVRZUNrN1V3pmNRlJVVIJQlGZiEEpkvuD/5PmiIbNLwX@Kgh@Te0uRoVopw9tsLs8ackPGb/AJW80XLSwyuDmU2rLSVRYL/g3ustLgfbYUIBAzgP@jvyCCdJVImUUGPYJPdssK5BdU2d2TK/lq8q@5A8TIYkkqAY2iZEnt9mGulNvfbR90c92c3MhpuU6rO1u/FClDQN9SrWmaGeSekNHqL0SzKEqoRXVcVQtcqrkQ75eqdUnO3b4qZjWfyx@2c9UqHyyX@7SjQGvoW4QrA4pGZNJoNZbSXymC0oLfnCT8hfJiDgrB68ClyMlqWaczMwwGX@81s/OMtaiz7slCTKETvWLdy1KdLaOKczFrhW2zKy7E7Ly3QL@bMxXmMcu79Xpul5f3K3Uw9GYuqTGgJilCBY0sm00wsO2oSBJwWAGimj06dHwhMxbquKTI1y9FVeTKTCpV1igTRQLEDz2Q5JTsGxAfuq4VkmAw2OHfIRCCDJJCIEBdF1NxzAOmQej2pxCb7giZiMLlnVl0Qul0MpnS5fXEiWrWhw8Q37LrLz/889/C7w/w@y1//va/qmW8/@WHf/zPP//rvwvw/Ie//PBP//GXH379O/j9S/L73e2fICBFO6S8nxZM4Tnmt1WTr/Y7@BlKIRV@AXR5E3uEWyhOjN4SwihD0JAHxWK1Uq5US8VKoVKt7JbNvXK5YBYL5n5lv2oUwFFWzL1KuWoWKrvV0u7ubhVqy9V9IUP9vjPQdfBApigSVoBgHQ@uNfCIX6CNWuDR@nTg@PQRmcl95VGmn34gkwoRS5WOAfkBHuoEjVDIHG2pTCKIqgFx2ShMwIqUDyYVcW9frOXgKR6IJSgyRZrJxJBA40SpI4pKu9o9EPfLYg3ctCo9Ng@IuF8Va@L@vqjURTosi@IeKe6L4lsHN3eJWF8AyikrlsQQsLuaRuCnqgLWj5scHZmIckdc02Ml@c9WkixJ@0VJUqQ6dLJzCwRpA9I4ZWK1KMLHkMaT0CdGfcFH/6u14cPLWhRbISaIrHfIn/aqIn4GkAafla1yL1crmGrhUOB6vGcKmYXQx8M4u9U6RghgOxstISvh8FJJyKilYDfIZLNZiCtetsSSeKo19CRYaOksUuhg8IBuW0tjj5YQUlyc7uP/LOPmv1JG9IckEprwXaij7RAzibG6RifU4V02PmfYQQtyNl8uWiYnz2vPkSdW7ZydMmx3ifL5O8edV0pqi0XhkA0sCLBmMT6vvtt/V3n3/NXpq9OTw1qlVgGDkok@KUHZ/Ox/U8/UxlJpVypBlNHMcATNfSXTKu5rkXWd6SbbYPLuvkLgjZmLopkZoEtcesRNj7lW2vI@vfJYmAWIVH7WHw6d4s@ev/8EebgkEWJm9z6rDf7XgNuTUy4hWdwriwpuH0bvLt5dZIRMmYjFMihLXofwVdf/pggTsVrdq@xlhB91/b5EHmqXeciAQog@8bYlIkeh89zClVN/mYxA4fkEMtblRCU4UzHFG7VufmOz98Yn9l8T4ZuAeDGtxoIVDu0CW84lOTxU2u7CLE63AmSsxdVoZbl4vVR9vsmAXTj1ZRFGwclGmgjAVAYiCdlpmnXiNLAzeEK6koyAV9oi38QipskMC6er1IX1VXmGSQtar@Gy1j6f5@ALjhanx/b6nGxet3wF9DzcvbTlpLVyC6BtdAFG6hhSQuaXkAH5qLzsoUB@Mhm32kNmpqQ0MRRWlcn3lSgWQi4ueHUByc6N68IvZVuZY8ZY/@w9fmy/G7e9bl3xmjE@83kP7Nal7HCQXNz0mqpZHwOy9bidzzvdpqf8Uh4z5L0mGjkYG3uOlPlS0n4zEVekFD62ffWz3y2ctP282S1MCrm3zY8Fq2kUZvADthXcwvfAvJSVctz8mPfrVgN@mLze4ASY67xVv7lZAk0uZbf5sW11m4ZSd6FhPn8CxACeUdvN57sKDO5C5WbDuvv4sZV3W7O6q6oKQr0rHZy0Yyh08018r8lWY3bwsT2B9jUZnk0YxlUAeWh3UwbQH@BXBx5z8a1Q5zjOEL0ZoOc1m7m3B7m3uebOzsf2TPW6Bc7@mrESPCI/Q@TXdUTOvV1XLMYSFp/J4ldO7SstFxGxANoHTC6M11pyDHNvoWa8mg2L/wY)

EmojiCoder, 96 [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)

For a change, I'll try simplified answer format. I don't like duplicating a lot of information in each answer.

@Chance: Sorry, no more exciting answers in my pocket right now. Only pretty simple stuff.

EmojiCoder is another stack-based emoji language.
EmojiCoder is not to be confused with [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/).

Commands in EmojiCoder must start at new line. The code is .

Emoji broke because  converts string to number in Emoji and there is no string on stack. To fix it I duplicate a string with  in Emoji before outputting it.

Answer (score 5):

## 98. [Archway2](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Archway), <s>2989</s> 2917 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zTvbcttIds9G5Q/2pQVyDIAkbqQoUbxJGlva9ex4pFiyvWWSlkGwScLChQOAImWZrn1KVZJ92GzlIbVbySSpStU@5C/2db9iv2D@YHJON8CLSEl2LlWBRaCBPt19bn0u3e2uFQ1/@imDFzkN3OuBG8QkplFMeqFzRUONfH1NDiwnKhdLgsCgwqA3th1/QOIhJY4/Gsek77g0EmwrJk0ySnrRsEAyJKRWj4MJ/SAk2IR4ly5xiD0aka5rDTWbuA7AHhsVQr3gvQOtosBDyJiGo5DCPSI@pT0Sjajt9B2bjUjoNKZ@5AR@pBHHviQTx3VJj7rQYIGGXYDOyDha@sQH1YReIBC47NEtpOdvWQowPk0JpyMrZIQHZMS4kNI/Ca3RCJAUMuQMEI8dj0bEiaWIUCtykJvQJKJ@j/FsNOdzQCx/mUpy5VjEAnzHIes7omEM5GmsXzKkIYUuLRx8EFoekSehEwMLkKWH5JRaITkPKVVgFBAFjWxrBHisDAmDBThCjIRoTGT1unR0ciyB6HgLzRrFQiYsnf/1N4JFtAbJXtTg1xDFmnD03VNyk21jGbCAzkC8o1C2FNL4RCK93abwm5pdfRDOBOhVAK64RA9GsW6pI0BQjQFB3cIiltSrojZylwYm9VuyWFIoDtUDaZBnPnlVYJTZ4zCkgMeCqdYlEO0G/gD4CcSGYx/54ZMdA0RgB34vKhB6BVwLfC6jYMI4fD50QGgRisTqAoMsG3nPJwNjKEwH0L2Eo@m4UeCOGRy0jGJUQOAKNMUen/XJK9K3HBebQD12xbEOaTR2Y2wz9nsoec/xaU8jKRp20EMgL7iC4SzolH2A@eMtzTqGFACDIAJGKlb95bd/6A0G0M@hbQdhL1HXV6QX2GMPELYYshaoIips4FsuQwvgCjg6bw4DXFmu07NiHN6/ToZgSLBRJ8HY7ZEABgwnDkytoXUF07Hfp3ZMuZIH4xhwLBDPuuS2wuGaC4R7VhcEywZgYzOyVXLwBKRkU64yqjeO@xWijo6IFOlv5f2qvL/VpoCboim5rK4PaqBvWo59gjfpPsV5dbiQJ2rPuRPgPHJHwzFYDajxoxHYkxCZaVtAToRmJQb7VyBdxmhmi0DV2SSdUCmkpAszOyWM6QjXAWyv4sxNeljINIVbVTHaW9Iw0E5QsjhaMxNuMIGBGW5oREGnfRzcGlgwVJwQdMgJ4iOyL6ukXfqg6dhbl5KK2nVAOqgHYGwSYSzRCOClIoeB3rj0liaFZ11DLzY30gtJEqcPQvZAb8NrYlOcDDArKLd0OMiYKUbkgB4FfWKoxXL5AeHHoX6ovgHr8UG/V8ZI/C0xH5I@nRDX8gdjawCKHPjQxLJtOoqTGQSURDHMkduGkH1UE6uuRUMhe3B7bGbdEnu/NAZaHy69xEZbqPbAKA9Yrbowy4kVDthMJD0nhPniXt8eHQCubg0uvkOQFQTeiXegkLomUDI6pfY4hukGijwZOvYQdBex8/mE5dbx9vDwaXl0MDlqfz40ImM2HxcFTZ9/QjTu7EJFia73A1Yfu2qufGDCX/5wf89W5G3oOJijCBZq6aumWxroXsI08OdnGEuA@UudN5tZ8wBjzk9g8DfomEL6/RgEBvrsDHwEsfy541@yjE7kS@AqnMgBrqMLR10/f3aC/uA15VEM8J37smVjHkBMA80TF40VqRAEag8DovpESnCQReZR3wNaehTarKAuhRGiogGfZOQXq0o7es9jtNsOlTTX4diQUoG0RLFTAB/mRqBC/th14WXssykmU@UGdM2mUaTBhAHeahiPAHZiniqzVcB4GAYTQmdKTdo03BcK5Mm460z/H0rERrz4HahaEgP79DlyWANMBSGKCevWIBjvngQe2nnymlGM@H4dgm/ogz8QRtfxECydahPRagQjCiitWBIJ8IQgXVZqLKSTJO194PjyjbS1tSVVpaZUgNI@lOpY2sdSHkr7rKSyEsJpWGItCqyEtS3WAr91pFkr7XmqdFC0U4xbPzgj2WpVq6VOwWqZybOITwWcCfgOgFbxAf1ISqOBRUURmxMgVOv2BU7@OQjnWwj5yLcOeuI@BIiL1EGYD9YWRM6M0qotFRc1RR6tXukesE8bXW@OIsTlrlgDCOAuA9TRRenC0MzySheQ96y37DvRkN1WQNfQWq9hrSOv22e3DQDVJAyAmAKzJOQLM2UYiQQBaP6EgXmBH3BUgF@Ob@kv2EMD77EJn1UjvYJMl8KcH1C96/hYfgBM3aswyH6369wFCnxB1NPnBrBw3N3ENgjPhmt@nKwwPh6HsUt7yfPPv@6BANbFM7SuIwjoL@eFC@Abikrt3ymtpCm@sNtmyb4fu5DuPdCHbWEQb7nzwua@quQFBfUHyfosywNMXaANIxwwdev6DVPDHfdo@tzcKePhajjAW/uOxyQHT4xtmOW5o/mtYIa3x6QndAOrp/NE1KELUXKm06k1CPxrfcmraWH3M3BM4w2yyDzj4Tge8zsmmw8JzRnh777JmEAaZatrUj2IrK5zBwcRiZ27lJbPBTTTat@1LnnxAoubSeXEhM4AMtv0eRcYRHsQkI8sm@oT9rjTfvjjaMSEyUr39Be6/H4XiOPb4Fn9ReEuQCDTZbcvUTmmCDbMA0QVF3vUJRY5t5jqWt1rdGXDL9cfHHCQzxMVbEfDzueNElGDRS62WFYaje5ub9tJ@729za35ChTrwA4gbaYP@SNwKo5nuWqxt1S8076mrn9R2mR@rCsLggLXikBB4oTN9ArEwm73KS36CXvsWuGidI/KLtBJU@67srZFm5FjB66TaGb6smEAH8O82yHRohtcV2S3RVN8S0zmU4h60PF@utduBnaMydIdqvMZFonnKZgJLumCFtzFLjuY4O/OCTsMrii/b3ZBHzZi9RkWR3WZMkCsvd68Zz@kobgOxG6bLeHlRqxi2934vUqeB0EIiWpEippxr3g2qnHkuEFEztj9Pl5Aih5F/L5ZgZfZ5li@ag/5tJqXNzfbiBTzaOSQ3e8QruUOAnenMtAtuN2pAeOwj4Y9eX6uUZsbJdN80CjNw5fAN5Pnndb8Ev4eUg5cAAHz7WAcMy9uVpQ7LVgS8d9NIIT5uOC1mbhjozLXrDCi96pUlRyG9nBiXd8L9ZDnuIvNqeeo4mI9C4T/Z8Ns3z9M7/Os1Fq3u/d3uyLeS5eCmWb3NaGSomF@YQvTMD7fZvXdMR3TjTbkpPueguJ8dlB8L1JGQkaVfLh07@3zs9BGL45v99ocy3Vgnj8Yw1TJKQTRp8EDCcDAH49WZLmcPYz9Fw/MiSdB0PtyTZ1bncrDoVCVnNH4ASyOvACS08CDkMD/DMkmoTrbVuT3FcmyL4ue3ztPIJ4IH0ABSpBU4xoUxKPuNV/Y90ZBaIUYaXTD4JL6q4akeF@XbAXjBdummq8bR4Vkfw2@OWGymxLNtywzz3w7pGwVOV0XIxlc2x57EIzFQagRBifLVj6vKAJvhM594ANYCsU2jXDdnu9HRQSirJjBOn3SapHszbRqVM0ZaRCxKpJOh/fKVpCPpiO22/OCN21lrU4jK6mqlJXafpUYEgOlLtjajaDWClzfYQ@O54J04lse2yrAckppje9HQAiEm1BDy@9B@vnSd9iSnx2EfFWdb92cY27/pz/2kr25AQUiPSeCiTXwcT858OgwmOzzcZPRD0cjC/f2sA/IeFy@KKg@OSTRxIntId@Sgwjt5fF5JdlPSXa54eUU884lLLhQoaoPOFgxFxrHphdQrhXJwPNWKVEQ9o49n0ycXjyMNIhnfJuy/Zp0DwEwCRHMj8MAtapAnpEexfSLrWm@H4Ns3SC4ZEupiMmf/sh3kaDSQRXCcjo829ZcGpGAGTLZ1o1tB2PAOu3kAw2DBERGJkPwPmYzIfAp/64Qe2ix7S3QRDXd3MFh@AbPk8Mzoh4RCbflca@n5vTl7OGLn79qGZ3GJ@Lp9M@/1nF5mfFN/ErdNSOxQFKQ2gz1arnagOpFrUTE7FRMyMINYLbfOVcqPpuIjGUmrnSzxmN7x0zv6IRt1rAdOR9zE9yU9SOYH/CqsK75pGlk5bHreE5M1LOYlPHsAhgxC0p8t5ngaQDceMAm2Sn5SIaoK6pNzLIBb5whLu51eY2v05Wx0vIKpv6Udscs278qasVSg5GTvWjUm6wU0l6Au6Gtt@1JR49SrrTb06@M4hTYFoQA/ljHmXP03dObrNY0Pn6MILwRxZlUYyvMOL2zN6fPTo/Ozg/PX54BG2ecysxxEHrWwkSgEoxciDuHgcu2l4EfoUOjh83GI2Y3hEcJoCyTrEXq4O0JWKhHc8OSsFVUxSwv8jpmSeZ1tyoT89F3SGLqyCmTdiJYKVo2c4VUAZB5MCfHYFdT5EFxbjaYK0aOSBpAkAoEMfA5wvO3TYSt1jJ4zvB9fAemJ2QsQzFSF1CbgZBWDpzgzWE4khuJmP0vYT4CP/Iw5gj1EOYALDw0@tLAx4fPvn354mh97KVhE5g1kLmGLJ3oOZpCvgB2sM80HHeNU70Jkl3/1DCA3R/yrSjLXZi2aL6rhJrUR8PswtzGScHW3CKc3ATtiEYO3QgMaa8HlqF7HaNhAYvKN5Lmu0liBhigzf1cgYgCwkaN9d1fMBwTiKzsd7xxlsGxnqNNByjaVP/Lb//AD020Yyj/bVLuQ/k3vPxWRwat77JzHOesQba8enZKIvBWnHDPmi7RhA4DHZLjQ1TueMDBK8YQBOfILuhd9CO3XgE/QQjATLR8aOzYeDTsyMM4HlV1Hf07pMd9jS3D0ynIAWylBgml/v0Yz7CAfdZ3yjvbpg5Iqldph2xrdIBLw7xDRamCCglXzqjxrmuTer1OxAhCOdrYqXFG6lnrbUl8N0c0C7ACDwVaBNpAk0ULqGsmzeSslTcVbIqzUDIl0qmBl@dyAUchswKAKPjZT/ghgicKElbhLiudxsyoXqchDsQXfkA85BM7yZR2pEJHvG9FFNZ0d7EEjFtfS9qsLYtBfI1gZwhWFTepDgEN@dcNmuND@e94udU21E@dTadw5rpzuH7YRr59VAZpIQdnfoBbAseAK5GLerGkmzvK0jwRk64AW5wVH6FLmAcwr2zqvA9G0eGTo2ffnJyerR0WYZDSbTCJSM16vq1qhVZnXpBu6XzK0q@P9bPnXx@njFzGKqm6jdWmzm8jdsdgr/li@/pQrGJtINP43I7ZzrB6zJLPDYTMa/UlwCd8ZXBtVFm5mbU69Wbbz6wN/3HTSa6MlsPDW1BqR@wcl0Q2GJhn6RbCOeZS0T1HVNQYIZwPy4dV0g0IPAlSbOo9eqXj0QVBW2xNiFm5voKtwo/TcB6kw4OdSL5kIflvksVYtrC2zLuMCM97gzkmKy3nzEaaT3hmx06jWT4E9aFjc@iIGVee/7GjU5ABPIsXSQMkIri4wXKja5YHwDSfL5v2HLaiboXXCQXzmjPqOep5ig9O@sX5AAfT2BjSj2joOt2a1WhNyXz3/L6jA1o0cp1Yxj37qYb5FVAjK0iAWXcpbvnX9zrJ@QKSHgPIs5MEp2Pg12kwIouc9ilNSy8grSFPx9A5aAAl34w9gOuzxwuKFp6S7wIVGgMfpRSJFowiJzRoXq8Mo2tDOu05A/ASslIAg/KVaS7OIFhKHnJRCWwoZ9XPcT14mTFfdG5iiWNWy9Icv0ensjSRlGoHuQPfpcnrK0kR13SAHd5ITnL0bp/iSOe@FSeTcH4CYnnipAELDJ7soYITwbO1eGoGEgUHdPrgl9T3QWVkQNsDBSHWGOgMlUJ60LswP463ZBd@kWzJ3vYSR9KNG4AvzOo1lpLUZuAQ3rVJO2732z56hdq1/jNd02s3ctZtXOvgyJWmnB02zHwpl89n/Zyc9dGVPX6MmcwsC57yQhM1cQpAatZVasBP8KyNrF/LWnU522sUc6wFvObzyg00@BTp2k3WmunZx@CYCvAl5NohZyMFxWFomjkD/FBCWb3gWaMbWSTiFE814vBZJ59HHLTsBSLwSW@f5ZmZap/pLHeqJQGSPvBSNV5Rhp9@ypg7EKvv75TkYL9Y2splSOZA1HPtp2/ePLmqSS2rX9S@75xenp7@SmnLUubJiWhuizWS04WMnjM@7ur6u3fvIHQgrabW1DpKS5U6Lbm5u5urFXYqucJBwZQKtQxxTcM0FblYVM7a237NcZxR1OvBLxjisSdwnlUUzSO4ZPNUksol6ewtHtfZ34J/7A@u@Svet9iX5DMDWb@2FCJ/PxUyzUegS6WdrYNHgCrNs6taPSBC5pOQuRYy7@rvhAxESJlmszOb5eutel1rNqdNtdNsCZkbITOdCZmiiKzJCZnGtP6CddF62uR95b8HNn8Lz7raaY1Ovz06PDsqFOtqpnh8@KRQPHv5dcaEt/LiFStL@Pri6PDpycvzQpG3@vmzV0cvT@F71GkeHOQ1VVUPtGYHsJh@lW/mG3EckzcXOZgbT5vTl7pah0G/FTIvGKTaBjTaCsB/FDKtTEveL26f7Jwc7BcN17gyzEvz8nlwMv8jz09OoMKZGu@D0BgaQ7NnmubUoC@Na@N6anjBidmDIoV/hgdFx@hPjYHhG75pLnd0z593Ejw/CaCrAJrFUyPGXo0@PAcnJ8@hsz4M/B7@OYaBCE6NK/gzXJNdby8grzLabaEFatop74yKO9@3mN0p73VadOrEHZEUpHZL6tQyetRu61zRxSJoKVbPZhcXTw/PDy8udEyfpvVs/iCvHsDVaObryWM/02si/7T6VluQ5Mnr16/x93pyNeElVng9Ia@TC950cbciBsFBAvp68Xw9gevqjk5WC2TlkuVWuXMzUxTlUVuqSZwSWabgSGXRbE@LfVIUmX/aA@tgliAHkHfKSrO5U4b3nYqiygbWbitvzXo9qSoqQShKUzEIJXIz4//km1ldZpeC/xQFPyb3piJDtVKGt@mNPK3LdRm/wSdsdTNrYpHB3UCpJSsdZTbj3@AuK3XeZ1MBAjED@D/6CyJIV4mUmWXQI/hku6xAfkGV7R25kt9L/jW2gBhZLEkloFGULKnVOsiVcrvbrf1OrpOT6zkt1252psuXImUI6FuqNQ0zg9wTMlrthWgWRQm1qIaraoFLNRfi/dJeTZJzt6@KuZfP5Q9aub09Plgu93FLgdbQtwhXBhSNyKTerM@lv1AEpQm/G5LwF8qzG1AIXgcuRU5Wy9rtqWEw@Fq3kb3JWLMa657MxBQ60SvWvSzV2DKqeCNmrbBldsSZmL3pztDv5kyFeczydq2W2@bl3UoNDL2ZS2oMqEmKUEEjy2YTDGw7KpIEHFaAqEaXDhxfyIxWNDtfLpf1ItynX@0cFadCDZcb@dqmqIpc0Ullj3WYiSIBYosuSHlCdg2IHV3XCknQ72/x7xAkQXZJIUigrotpOuYIkyB0exOIW7cEXMyEyzu16JjSyXg8ofPriRNVrffvIfhl148//NPfwO@P8Psdf/7uP/fKeP/xh3/4j7/8y78J8Pz7H3/4x3//8Yff/B5@/5z8fn/7JwhI0hYp76YFU3iOye@eybcCHPwMpZAKvwDCvLE9xP0VJ0ZXCjGWIWjIhGJxr1Ku7JWKlUJlr7JdNnfK5YJZLJi7ld09owBetGLuVMp7ZqGyvVfa3t7eg9ry3q6QoX7P6es6uCdTFAkrQCSPB@XqeKQw0IZNcHc92nd8@ohM5Z7yKNNLP5BxhYilStuA5AEPkYK6KOQGDa1MIgi5AXHZKIzBxJT3xxVxZ1es5uAp7oslKDIZT2ViSKCOotQWRaW119kXd8tiFXy4Kj0294m4uydWxd1dUamJdFAWxR1S3BVFSiTyBqVIxNoMsE65MaeHgF3WNAI/VRWwftTgGMlElNvikpYpyf/vkmRJ2i1KkiLVoJOtWyBIHlDHiRP3iiJ8DGk8Dn1i1GZ89L9aGj68rEaxFWICyXqH/GpnT8TPAFLns7ZZ7uaqBVMtHAhcl3dMITMTenj@Z3uvhhEE2NZ6U8hKOLxUEjJqKdgOMtlsFuKO86ZYEk@0up4EE02dRRJtDC7QrWtpbNIkuhBSXL7u4X9n4w6iUkYCBiTK5P@blwYjNKBPoYaWScwkpvAaXVybI1T/lGEnQ8jpzXxJNDkqX32OHLWqZ@xYZKtDlE/fOe5NpaQ2WYwPucaMAGNno7O9t7tvK2@fvzx5eXJ8UK1UK2CuMtFHJSibn/xvapnqSCptSyWIYRoZTpy5q2SaxV0tsq4znWSTTd7eVQi8MWNUNDN9dLhzf7vuj5dKG94nVx4L4gCRys96g4FT/Nnzdx8hy5ckQszszie1zv/qcHtywuUriztlUcHNyejtxduLjJApE7FYBlXL6xAc6/qvijCT9/Z2KjsZ4Sddv2@ZAGrnWU6fQgIw9jalOYeh89zCdVl/nupA4fkY8uH5TCc41TGBHDZXv7Hpv/KJ/V9K@CYgXmxOYMEKB3aBLRaTHJ6CbXXADKQbDTLW4lq3Ml8an08cvoWBXTi1eRFGwalKGgjAVAbiFNlpmDXi1LEzeEIylIyAV9oi38AiJuEMC6ej1ITlNX@GSRNaL@Gy1D6f5@Azjhanx/Z6nGxeN38F9DzcG7XlpLVyC6BldABGahtSQubnkAHZrjzvoUC@mIxb7SHvU1KaGAqLyuT7QhQzIRcXvJqAZOdGNeGXsq3cYD5a@@Q9fmy/HbW8Tk3xGjE@83kPrN6l7HCQXNzwGqpZGwGytbiVzzudhqf8Uh4x5L0GmkgYG3uOlJu5pP1GIq5IKXxo@eonv1M4bvl5s1MYF3JvGh8KVsMoTOEHbCu4he@BeSkr5bjxIe/XrDr8MDVe4QQY@7xVW92KgSaXstv40LI6DUOpudAwnz8GYgDPqOXm8x0FBnehcr1hzX382Mq7zWnNVVUFod6W9o9bMRQ6@Qa@V2WrPt3/0BpD@6oMzwYM4yqAPLRblQH0B/jVgMdcfAvUOY5TRG8K6HmNRu7Nfu5NrrG19aE1Vb1OgbO/aiwEj8hPEfllHZFzb5YVi7GERX@y@JVT/UrLRUQsgPYBkwujpZYcw9wbqBktZsPsvwA)

Archway2, 98 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway2.c)

I compiled it with gcc 4.2.1, gcc 5.2.0 gives error "lvalue required ...".

The code is on line 62, it is similar to [answer 74](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125682). I use the fact that Archway2 deflects one position earlier from `/` than Archway
on line 68 (penultimate). To deflect it to line 62 I added `/` on line 61.

`#` is for zkl. Incident as usual.

Comment: Wow. Almost at 100 languages! And you tested this in all 98 languages, right?

Answer (score 5):

## 113. [ADJUST](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ADJUST), 3746 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*\DZZCv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdohcoding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@   x/ "78"oo@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----
#~
#z#111#y#y#1111111B#_#xxxxxxxxx
#`<`
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[       _ 
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q   L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>4O6O@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                           _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0  )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw                       (([5]{})))␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(\"ar_\"[2]==95and 3-94 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # 
More 91 of thiset of re9
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":     x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");"1015""6 27""Zingeg-' x?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9    >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3             #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                x_
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint ("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002596 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 3846 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid-Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tX1dc@NIktizEP4H@1ICOQ2ABEGCFCXxU63pVu/2zPRIbnXPzA3JZoMgKKIFAhwAlKhWa2L9cne7vrDPe@uNvbnzzu2GHbER9tM5HHGO2whH@F7vV8wf8PyDcWZV4YNfknrPpkSyUJWVmZWVlZVVlQAHRjD@4YcMvsiJ51ydOV5IQisIydC3LyxfIx9ekYeGHVTLFUFAqEP/bDax3DCoCxmiE9s17SFcktA7t1z7reVDdplMfe/MNyYkHBshsQLTmFoB8WbhdBYSb7S@VoUcTbw3dgErTmz3DKBCy5/6VkiLd8hL1zEmg6GxVFBdpDb1oTggjy3n3eRdSExvMjHcYSAw9k98bzgzEXs4tgARMjSyHSsQTKjbJlMuBA0TJEN8yxgyMGHk@QSrkMm5Q2xiTqdk4BhjzSSODbBPSvvEwgaQt1CeIYE3sdKcBsS1rCEJppZpj2yTUiXWPLTcwPbcQCO2eU4ubcchQ8uBCgkrpgrIyCxIZTHCmjD0BAIvc7rEeHyVtQDGtaLGW1PDp433UGggiUgGl74xnQKTIM9TYDy0J9BhdigFxDICGxUCqgSWO6Rym8aq4hHDTbeSXNgGMYDfmU9xB5YfQvM0ipeMLd8ClEbcY/Klb4cgAhTrITmxDJ@88C1LWVScBZJAzEMKITZEo93WbEpHx08k6D5WQzOmoZDxKy/@9UeCQbQWyfYb8G6JYkM4@vQxuc52Mc1UBbp46suGQlpfk6DY7VrwnuuD4pl/IwBWAaTikKI3DYtGYQoMFkJgsGhgElOFi7I2dVKESXOpL1JKxaCG0BvkqUs@U2nLzJnv41hIhGqcQ6Mdzz0DeUJj/ZmL8nDJbgm6wPRAm1ViXYDUPJf1kXdJJfxibEOnBdglxgAEZJgoezaeqUBhRIPucYlGdAPPmVE4qBmEqIAgFaiKGJ@OyGdkZNgOVoFyRMW49q1g5oRYZ@YOsedhyFpDjURsmN4QgSbeBZAzACnNgDE0SY08yhQAQ0d4tKlY9N1f/s3w7AzwHJqm5w@5un5Ghp5JLY9BmYUxTVBhPddwKFsApyJ1Vh0IXBiOPTRCJO9ecRKUCUr10ps5Q@IBQf/ShqE1Ni5gOI5GlhlaTMmZuVLJxDhn9sJmmgsNnxgD6FhKgNKmzS6Qh4@gl0yLqUxhMgtH@6QwPSJSUHwlH9Tlg@2uBbwpmpLLFotnDdA3LUez4Eq6TXE@O0z6E7Xnhe3hOHKm4xlYDShxgynYEx@FaRrQnADNSggmXCUDKmhqi0DV6SC9tCTfIgMY2VHDqI4wHcD6BRy5HEPSpxHcoopZw5SGgXaCkoXBiplwvEsgTHlDQwo67SJx48wAUiFv0CFrEKNIcxabdu6CpiO2gUX2CwMbegf1AIwN74xUGwG8UmYwgI31XmpQTIwrwGIyI530JLFH0MkT0Fv/ipgWDgYYFRazdEhkRhUjgOkLJ7JSoVyt3tH5oV88LHwJ1uNt8dY@xsYvdfMhGVmXxDHcs5lxhjOoC1UM07SmIR9B0JIghDGybAhpZoFbdS0YC9mHy7SpdeP2PkUDrQ/rPW6jDVR7Po0WHBjlxOA@ABnaPowX52qZOgBcLBEXXyPIAgOvxQ0sRFMTKJk1t8xZCMMNFPlybJtj0F3kzmUDllnHZfKQlaYOJqcwikkjM3r7QVnQinEWsrERRQF7dBUPWH1E1V7IoJ2fzrgdsxFM1iD2YhbBQqVytaKhge5xocF8foq@BJi/aPKmIyt2MGJ5goBhqMMwBWUZh@E0qIO5scPxbKBBtxZf@FdPw2MXe7YY@ld26LH0wPEGxYkRwGAqRhSK5mxgz5daRPNigb8JhAuYxkcBaYH9/2oGKiJLo0BSGjT/EQKnikQ6tVIU7FMEQAqkgaTkUaChC/YELMDplWvKokb1XoMRIqpExFEmKpDAWrFcHnkTNBnkczq9oL/woQ9mZgSmRZhehWOQQ8EkotHyppYrSwtKKSmUoKw0qHcgSdobz3bla2l7e1uqS21JhdQBpJqYOsBUHlIHNFWgKYTTMEVrqDSFpR1aA/N60k0nwjxXethtc3SB3tpT2ejU65WeanR0/l3GbwXsEpghgC7gF@CRlFYLk4oiti@hodpgxFr/nEl2SLXhueWeCdZ86vkh@fT48VH/5PDFT1picRb4RcceFF2YEPsTGG7gAotr6oMvG1WH5HPPC1u0wzCfQj9Ne7gj35vE1iEQLHPsETFbEdEzW/DttelVVLqDpTPu2mM@RfsEaHMXXgi9GYx78IrtiR0@pb644@KISXQhKn0EzWEIXoAF@wRcKPKJHdA1R5pRIZZ4VxCZRlQWbZOYlJSZ93cBYwHs7PRq/awsplHRCtDOcw8HYZLqlzS9uoAC1hKrNUd2MKYfC6ArbK2W0NrBZDCiH2sA6nxahTkaVx0ol4/QZ8WZ3fNghXJJwSae6zFWQF62axSf0y8NrPE6fhaN3gIzA2s0Az@2OLBdTN8BVqjtU8jRYGBvAgW5IOvR9xowfzZYJzawgeOVeZEsCD6c@aFjDfn3P/90CB2w2j1j4yoAB/k8TvRBbthVhdHG3uJV8YJ@rO9ZCvNm5tgGFQNN3YXSNNBHNpw4sR41DnRSKIwNHzr3KupcUE78AKN9l/rDyHFmQyv6Xk@Einhx9mW1XXtCWwTf6EpQ67yh@pLvwOrjGsN3PGNIsbC1n20lvc36xZobZ9C4Ymo9qvmDe/AZTfEkWezB9BjO2Ceu7@7qV3uK79vGK4csVY2BbhW9wBjYG6SITOxu0ms2XHA6K4wc45wl@5hc31TWGN8@g8Vk9L0JDBws8IGnhmkVL@nXRhPjzoIp6wpM3YLPd9jnJpBoJyhObAKEZjr0433UjiqCCWMDWcX9lUJKRPaSUB1jcIVT/vj99QcJnuXzpADmpWXm86UKKXjJ8ifZyZlON9c3TV6/Vltfm236UASmBytV664xC/OOPTGcQnmYSm40wZGLlKTWgL4xLgxwnhwjAAUJuZitC@gW@nGb0uJUYs4cw09St6hswk60yt20UErqTG3Tc2yumdHFJlu47LUmaHA7j34kVfFqVb5DcBRxmi7EqfUD2jNDXKxs0KN7mCe2TsCVWEoxNG@T7EzvEt8bR@/Yu7DY5/op6@1aru5hfgoO1QxYfKxWH5p3qSvuw9CP9VI8X8tVaDpr8@vkmef5sFAMSFkroYPj0s1DmLAdh62FXjw93qzTge14ATmln7fJAjzaIGCf67U5LTbbcAvmmI2xOL2@2lqm6PRGDunnhs41nDPP2d0/KxrwsVEDZv4IrTz/vq@Fiy2Urt9poWJ3x3N1/r3RtJ/D/13KgRsQYMttdHTi5C1e1DpzxpdJmxsIywLccFrfuCel/Viz/MC6VaVYV/jm@NK4ir7/iHlkk5yjeWR6Rd1m8OuwQm0fEqHPXOk/htrO7dSG97NWK2j37mpEqpvPHQtsN/1c6VxSLunvWUMvle5vu0bOzJpZa23J8eCNBQp0W5ffn6kSb0aWr6iLIDw8M4qh3vJF4b24xpkdr241PYZjw3C/069Za3Sm4GtPcSV9AokTTKxWPHNn04XOTcnu@cx9frvkxtNojHvDBSax5H1t0/7d3tOCQx5Y9L3elNTxTBKWvt4EvAn3Hv3PkdLdDva5gJjmJJjf2Lhh4d@Kt07iHTLwZMEzgV61z4MC7npsmgMWDU9505qdAtdqsCpzrfAKPzdJe51JHXie8z69A5Z1aKPDBm4oHp7e1Ut1cno1GYAPZybbd/fogWjBCNLCxfHGjj0BlOE9cVZWt69uma9Sm1lrKf/Yc9rN9h2d/hzHrq7ta3t3AD4@/vDok8P7Yatplft4QtPIvaV7argPx3beklPezJJ9mV6BZOxhITDH1sSil@stTJ0cPv7o5emLTWzUEYrvQ9Jjz/gcIlD5eS3k2T4/nQviI/DMU9f0LXoqEW18kwyelcwmsNIIPV8jFE6WjXxeUQRWCZ3VMxfAIih6CInnQOx8MyCwhAgprD0inQ7JXs/rpbp@Q1pEBF57PYaVnkgczaf09PA5q9rJGr1WVioUpKzUdeukJFFQywHfYS2osQA3sukX4zNpOnGNCT16wnTU0gY73wKXHg81x4Y7dCzyEoYAXeh4PjulYUeBL3Bv659@P@RnvWcWNHJiBzBDnLkYn@BNrLF3ecDocuqH06mBZ8WIA5bzDjsgKjw6JMGlHUKf0yNeWHG8fPJin5/P8cgJuDhBW5PignUqjj7gwQhZpzFuhp7F9IITjmtFjYI13Wzikkt7GI4DDfxz17To@V@86wwpBHND30O9UslTMrRwb2GIjL2ZQd86nndOd7eRk3/6PTuVhEIbVQjTEXl6TJ6iSHAU0aNA0/RmwHWE5K3lexxERiHDynSGxhq02mL5CjHHBj0uBU0sRIeFSIYdGD46PCWFIyJhmAeeajTskZw9fP7jzzqlXutrMila//zTonLN5SZ@UNjTA1ElEUjjBvUqXVyC4qRUImJ2LvJmYUABPT@PlYqH5siYpt0VHf5NaCwC1Tvrkh7@0RNeF@04HvK7AYwPuFQoajZoWll5xixH4TQkVYyFsUAkkGLRCwSjS/AgC6tk5@QdGaOuFEyiV0twxQTi4NnppPVhtDNcSe/gFx9bgxndyrooa@VKizYn22@BWcWUbw09PF3vvOpe9opBJJVud/5BqTwHsXk@gD8o4sg5@vTxdVZrl969C8BHF8UbqcFOJmB4Z69Pnp4cnb44fPHyFMR4w1qZeeL5EyMxEagEUwfWUWPPoeEKIA/ftoK7zcYWtRvCFgeUZZI1SBO8VgIWais2LFysYkHMsiQro5YkLlsq5OZjZBNu6sgJ7W3esVKQNnNqpAAoPBiTM7CrEfOgONdrzBVtjkha0KACNIiCxwzHV@satlhK4ZnAD/AahM6bkYaiTU2g1gNhWxkw55vBMCbXNuLm/xHnU5hH7uYcoe7iHICFu6inCD85fPrJy@dHq7RTZDnMCkisIakIsaM5eGlgB0dUwzEKIdIbj0eRRIYB7P6YnTUbTmLaAnJhB/bAsagmjdAwOzC2cVDQDeUABzdBO6KRQycAQzocgmUYXIVoWMCiavRYkJ0NFlwiZkAAWjzPqUQUEDZorUYTgOG4BC/TfM0qZykcxRysC8jpWsXv/vJvWBBON4T0z3h6BOm/YOlXRRTQatQG4zEWDYrls6cnJIDZijV8YsxTbcIJAyck24XVpT0BCV5QgSA4YzZpb4JH7nwG8oROAGGi5UNjR@lZfk/GY/x6sYjz@5nnjDR6DGXNoR/AVtJT/a9mGBMF9rm4W93d0YvAZOEiQliwGcLClCFUlDqokHBhT1uvByZpNptEDGC1YbV2G0yQxazxqiK@jhnNAqzAXIEOgTpQJakBZW1eTc4aeV3BqjgKJV0ivQbM8qxfYKKQaQJAFMx2uTxEmIk8LirodNeah9SoXkUuDvgXrkcmKCcaGRchKgAihlsRhRXdTc438Og3pc1auhvEzxHsFMHq4jrV6bwi3bDr9ngIFwGF@bs1iuRC@udr4rpi7TlcDd@Sl4OvsDXk4anr4YnXE@CWyOViuVLUd5XUSBE5KuAXx8U7QAkjAUaWadlvvGlw@Ojo6UfHJ6cr4UcUUloGk4jUbua7BU3t9OKEtKT1kVA/fFI8ffbhk0iUaa6SBSNCJKvGZTbXUVvmdAP1z9nh0iptWrBCSC/dFzFdchae0I2VVexJaTEF@Ihtfq9QlZXrm06v2e66mRXy79YFC2a0HCoXpLoBDRWUyBqb8zQ6MnuBUdSBFkVUlMUkEtYU6Nrb49dJ9uagpDgmOwlNig7nMDCp3IaF4UXRnTmOoG04toO2a0VGikblMMYifsHWRKzqyGpC0BRWjj7S3BDeltXwcagZ9w4K6ZitDmmEpOHCwsC3TQYdUAPN1pA0nA9WEU/DZOEBixncEqDrqyu6lgBTER8lDG165GT4UfhKXHJqTezCi4gfNBxJoBEYMgygGUPbHHvQMFqdOYkjUG6LQdKCqWOHMgb/zDVco0FrZAUboDcdC2OHmrUeD1QiUTxRnoYkncxAXifelCTr4sdWlHoOSyPyeAbIQQ0s8tFsAnAj@vXcwlnCIp96BagMcpQiJjpAReZt0CbDKlDXxtZ8aJ/BTCMrKpikD3Q9CWYylDysZyWww0xUP8YzkrRg3isAKyUxo2Notju05rJ0KSn1HkoH8qXLzy8kRVzRARoFxkPChsvhYJGxMEI@apNQqiWDUKvFhmBx7NRq2jgQMDgIvHugeBr6n0AS5lB5NDGmRJ7ReLqAaIReyl3ZVYPQV0ihjfPZJXFJPk/XBfBFCzRCa45oynZwx0XGIGa52IJ@xtzAHeLXW3tKOrqm9SBNiSgki0v6R@Bu4GJYEcCJhCp1ihYmYPirI0eXsAJCjth3lpIVcD3uA9TaYjqQz8Z0AIIsaKtJ@wFJrEEyAplUa7U6741Fc1gjoBbNNRYD0K4xc5HHCfLlER4gNTRiAPUIVno2GJSHH1uuC@NVBp2ZwOgkxgyUzFfU6OYVNY7PzVAKGcbiT3jICDCaWTDER9K144E/ky026LKycQPz/usuTvwjPvVfFX9U1IqNaznrtK6K4IwpbTk7bun5Si6fz7o5OeuiO/LgAa5Gb7Lg7fQ1URPnAFTIOkoD9Bm8o1bWbWSNppwdtso5WgMu83nlGip8HRS166xxU8w@AG9ChRyfjU45Gyg4HEqapt8AfzhCskUVdOZaFok4x0hnJJ@183nkQcv2kYGvi93TPJ1XuqdFuv5tcCe3eDaJzMiirxL3xMr9NEyAPLseW/QqWnS@c9iPgDGsL9odXVO2zj/64YeMvgsrvYPdiuwdlCvbuQzJPBSLue7jL798dNGQOsaorH3VOzk/OflC6cpS5tGxqO@I0JhXDZIrCplirvRur1h8/fo1OJ@k09baWk/pFKReR27v7eUa6u5@Tn2o6pLayBBHL@m6IpfLSpF0T0l3zzBy@Z3yQ7dh2/Y0GA7h7Y3B3wY3rIUqsgUvWT@RpGpFOn2F8Z8HB9vwR//hFV/i5zbN4dkUZPW1rRD5q7mQaW/N/4hXUdfLXVytVXa3H25Be608fdXrD0Ei8yIR9/ZFz3u4vnYBX0LmayHzNqPreuYK/nT2@jDTz8RwQuZ187WQAWc/0273bm7yhY72Kq9p/V6@kG92mk2t3Z63C712h68x@0TIXAuZ@Y2QKYvYeTkh05o3n1PeOo/bjMn8VwD6CXw3C73O9OSTo8PTI7XcLGTKTw4fqeXTlx9mdLiqJpdYWMHL50eHj49fvlDLrNaPn3529PIE8oNev71zvHv88GFeg7Y91Nq9DvDxQb6db4VhSL7s5zSy@dVfk2KXQuZxe/6yWGgCu5/wnOeURqELV10FKL0TMp1MRz4oH5RLTumipJ/r58@84@T/@Bjy7XnpjeeXxqWxPgRBz0vWy9JV6WpemnjH@hCSFvyVJpC0S6N56azkllxdX8Cz@X9y7D079gCVB9XCeSlErKURfJ8dHz8DZCMg/Ab@7FIJ@ZuXLuC/5LBOf9UvEaKUul2hQ8TXFgwhTZe0kqTtSpLdq@5Ov7q@Ke9@1aHza7XW61hzO@yJRJX63U6tVpN6jUwx6HaLzKiI5R2xgSA3N/3@48MXh/1@Ebcb5s1s/mG@8BBerXa@yb8OMsM2ClRrbncFSb78/PPP8f355cUlS9EEy/s8Lkxf0AS8LjbUXUxsUAFZ7lR71zeKomx1pYbEWiLLFjiNsqh35@URKYvUF6uBJdYrON/vVpV2e7cK17v7SkEuYSmr0BWn02lX1OjaVKMnrK3Woe8bV@iPyjsKTAZd0fD7XbFT7rVatSrWrRRqO8TzC7WKIirKK73Z5CTKCmSL0lz0fIlc36T/5OubpkxfCv4pCmbyz7YiQ7FShav5tTxvyk0Z8yALa13ftDFJ4a4h1ZGVnnJzw/LgU1aaDGdbAcHhAvz/078XkGBKpMxNBudzl@xUFVjeW8rOrryfr/G/1jY0RhYrUgXaKEqG1Ok8zFVyezudg16ul5ObOS3XbfcW7JwiZQgodaSELT2DMhQyWuO5qJdFCZWygZvanmNpDiy2K7XGolZIfTm3/NrXa/lc/mEnV6sx2rncu20YP4AOiInwyoAiE5k0281YuxKUShve14QLHNI316BwrAzcA5nvXne781KJwjcGrex1xrhpUPTkRpQaC3pL0ctSgx5riNdi1vA7ek@8EbPXgxt0o3K6Qmfr6k6jkdth6b39Bkybeo6XlKCEJ6HACgyTDmCYKVGzJBC5Ao1qDawzG2ad6YKM8tVqtViGz/kHu0fludDA7X921iAWRDaQyH6NIsyQIKgJ4KkPoOMvyV4JVmKOY/jEG422WT4sOcjAssDrsxwHN87QIwfH1BlewipwW8iAwQF/FIrhNTkxrJllXc5ml1b8emQHdePNG1hQ0tf33/76T@H9e3j/gn3/4r/Vqvj5/bf/4b9895vfQuY/wvt/wvsfvv/2r3/K3vT6D/D@X6m8P/B3Co69BcD1b7//9pe/@/7bv/gG3v@Jv79Zfn/3q79n//@b/2Hyt9/96g/4wS4A169//t1f/zmw@CtM/xmk4Z9n/4wnU7ks@bMoCfX@dgn4599/@1e/4@k/T4Ok8qHqzyD/N6n8nwkCduY2qe6pqqZp8IHfKn3Rby37KgLRN8@wGSI8w827ms6OMm2sAinfqgk/AT2Y4B0feMdhiJ4cLPBKgoZaUy7X9qv7tUp5X92v7e9U9d1qVdXLqr63v1crqeDE7eu7@9Waru7v1Co7Ozs1lejlam0PHH53aI@KRXBAdFEkNGG7JsayN/GmAE8bt4XM0BrBKmqLzOWhspUZRhlktk/Eyn63RES20JOJQq5x9pNJAOt94FwuqTOw@dWD2b64uyfWc/AtHogVSNIWz2VSkmD8ilJXFJVOrXcg7lXFOjiOBemBfgD@WQ1WgHt7otIQoRlVUdwl5T1R/BI03jorSGR@IDZugO1IHnGDCEyVmkbgDT4clk9bjCdZrMmEjo1aV2SWgw1DSZakvbIkKVIDkGwTMdUzSgMbCO1jzYv4Q56AvxpMeQ3fCme@K9cKYIZJoaY0bhhL/yrFk38OS07Dx2UfJVkn4m5NxGwAaco1JNWuDnJ1VS@oDwVmE3Z1IXMjDDFod6dGGrUGOo8wbzXbnLmPydXeWf4nKXYbQlZChqXKkn7Rs0VCwBUrVLwdL5PNZsFxfdEWK@Kx1m8WuefZLlK3s9tu5Fs7j/LUkdMiDxfIFld1d2dH8C085BviTeTMLdivoljOSJABdI38H/PSgG4LkAoNnDDEzJRNWVfouJMu47X5dYa6DuTkOjrEmbl0R6r@DHvNqJ/SWyM6PaJ8/antXO9XCm26fpOhlwj0081p7dXeq/1Xz14evzx@8rBU36/vd7vLTZyDUxu8U7yq/rX7USNTn0qVHZRwt5Vh7dX3lEy7vKcFxlWmx6MT5J09hcAVnTXKemaELljiqa14aKnUmuvLiwldHQAj@z8anp3Z5R89e/0uWyxKEiF6dvfrQpP9N@Hj0TFTIFncrYoKRnUEr/qv@hmYG4hYrqJ@54uEm//0XDnPufTPygX0z7KSjAAuoysst5QcrPK/KIMNqtV293czwg/F4m3bsVAa70@MLFi3zybrNigOffuZgZs3brxJAYlns7eWD98wigLPHsbGiqC1wh04NFfpPG7BUln0AQmLeVdBEUMuMBcsOd5Kb@KOGBmhxZDR8wnpYR7J4eMpMNREEa6FLcA1M0MarQEfDUHYwsNJvJQjOJU8CEIFD3lKirC1xWwEAGtB2EfkWIlnFvSGcCOgeIzhMCC4d0TPbFh8ioHHgt6UBYo5V4RVCqidFZC3HA0tQbophnNkxLiA1uQIpUg5x8Yx8lsMbDAbIStPnn5yBHVIi4zoHiSvLfoDvJOUNm97pHDipARZiAXBqaQoOAICOsiUKW5lgkEwpkwh80TH8hHdywQomIdUyolKRrxiBy97UB3Rj0zHCwAxoy6zFpBcn5PlbeD80EaACLF11FxjwvDPTJX3Ht5E1enBHBUd48tYSpqkrMQHz0nbhC3oC1ThkYdRPPShAJcewXBD/tQSFtLDjheHiO/Soke3cd/RJ4pEt1PTR5JQPszJkOkhveOX9xplTu@poCkNdgQtx3A8J@HtRsiF6qTBen7aED6WTeUat84aX08ePDBfTTuTXkOZtEL8zucnMBmdyzYDyYWtSQu0bdqxe42wk8/bvdZE@VjGa5jnWiUAHrG@CxQuKhCk2wJecHs9UNS3HbfwtdtTn3TcPLA8U3Nftt6qRqukzuFtt3TVUb9q6bwdQDNsvc27DaMJb9zFWzjmh4k5bzQWT/6hyrnstN52jF4L5OFAxXz@CTQG@Aw6Tj7fU4C4A4WrFRvOgwdG3mnPG06hoCDUq8rBk04IiV6@hdd12WjOD952ZlC/LsN3C8g4CjAP9bisb2Legb8GyJipSMI643GO7M2BvUmrlfvyIPdlrrW9/bYzL0x6KhN/vZQoFzI/R@YTrkGrc18qZEkkdHEjix/Y9Q@0XEBE1c7nQcjqNFWTcZj7EkqmML1yrm/Q/NLnUkQ7xKhh/Mif3YpM7/akBz74nBkMZPIwD2OPoO5hYNo2B2dBY1MbtNvAB12osBxxCwaFwDL@5BYs7M4PDoSIND@PBspoq2CMGBjyRR@T4ONSiz4FKDB9G59Ic7u5XmfVIxMeO6KnT788IuD0VnZTo59aOjrgAt/sIAhalevSTYMZQBaFALaLGiOAocYI4QpolFBI3OxwyBYvRCeXdxDUQrMzYtHKeLNwgOYOrGU0WHUYTZwNGMxr2LDVNy1q6kCfbEgRu0npQQKGirAFjUAesA12j7TBLpIHDwi/bLbAkd/DqQXBEO5NXkegFU6B@D04BRzI5RvQUTSvlAjwtoUlGDyzQGjnX0aIB6DJUCH/RmVxaFr5C1HFk5iAxV2i3BTGBvbF1tYbcEg5Q/BPnXGoD2U3P2S491Anj46fnbx8cfT82eEpfOrlnX0hQ7jLUI8f2rLy9IcpPtVhYLs0UsQ0nuvWn3xkgjsEviWolDfEhwQNyUcvP4EF16ePVbzxAkSPcXwWnZ/rMSYroDe2B5rnnxUv7XO7uPgQL6jEZg36vLACPT4AHwnZoXO9k0SDJsGgAS4FYXrh0eILz5eaWEHAH2pRiB4zRR@lReNiJxjeCaOQPwSDnvdFRxb0gAx3GVR67OrbZzZ9dtCYIVioTx8sELLqdHwI@PCKoREaqNFCbb9UqpOSigk9SpSjRCVK7ESJapTYjRJ7UWI/StR4Qo8w6wyzXt6vVHaT5F6S3E@StTi5U0qSCYadcpKsJMmdJFlNkgm1nZja7j7FSzKRNOnQtXws03f2ozIM53ZDmlkFNPpy5g4wWl6BhOo7K5lAb38xE5b4nNDT4jEClcu7yTVYnwi2JTOuVMaHyiizK54Jc5XA1lJUYY98H6zS0RwfrQNKp9QJRusJAphdYjqWAc6AFYKX0noC@m8pdRb17V/V40nKQgwtPb6G6hasf6EOPiWPcPVZU1xeV8ywlddiY3HzJBZMKlyRM8m4rC8GIlKMOwt5aazbaGBRohsgygwC@yDh0knRfOHP1pKs3E5yAeFakitMMbzVdbVQNjJF3oqq0vmfYmtF9JifYtHeBjeAP6SO6sBSh2L4f@tar4vff/vNfyXff/vL35LvfvPb//MP/x7Tf48f/x18FlKOAX7xS/z4W/z4j/jxG/z4VaoSha/Uxe@@@Tu4/Hf/mXz3p79kRX/1O1HdiRFBCWYlNX/9Z/jx5/jxP0S1GgP@@ucMEKuI6o2w4FrJAPWLfyQEqCGWGNk3vydEzIODIXPN67Ax3lOUJQSxGDo01VsuZ5/m2Eexl5S8CHj5lZ5c5bEDlBRy38CnriVjD9wZFiWDVto0zDFGpPIsL0D/x0QXxgu0M9C3yyE4PXwvQoLW/xtSJ1IeYSCb3vXQYjact5@3W0xKETYvFoE7fGQMR4VpJeYEVssC6DddCVwFGi5b6AJXZzrC5fspro@iCUSMNMsOZV0ROK2oNix6CH8UGfwnK2dUWpyG2F0D9CF1Ag@u1FMEF8zNUrcBleUcWIEmsc3pqjTDmkyhS6BaLG8ULF5QKajL6JKe48Pm6PjJ0oDB1wBczPO0RYoJtYgo3gGLkubwCnpclUV4xi8H6JTqlZ6QjrJeByx@8cUXopDKK6EO@UOZYkg1ipmMuEhfLCqnisqpIuCZ4aS2plouL/FAJw60i8pyXPmiiVqsligXjpyoH5ANWAuybUd15MyCcWsVNbXIi8ZuFXkKpd5r8XHSdanNaRNRWakAOBfrtJb7cj3q0grMaketr4nSXshZ6K3NmBbqpAYFlZ6wLKW45/Taup5bJHgLar2XvyehculfSKhwT0K71bsJLXcr1l1Av1m@d5udyEzEFj5BxgZ@ZmGCwqnxG1C9xBwhxz5NygoseQ75kmdw6RF5zWPsIL8Y3Xm58Ow6P3U/Ji5iPvVCi20PPJx6sOTw0AtOPTp13WOG@ZNKz1zPt4L07Q42Cx11JbyVxvTOXJjVVLwD1OZPUcQbwNitjYvzSjyzcS/0EXsaK6JmgkLPs9@3XTvs98H5dEZKIkC81EyM55MEfIwrpFL15di1PZ7KHt65Hip346T@Lqv2wjbP5eMpL5SAyCGBBZ1pObD4ImPDPMcHElORYBPpzQfokQ5CWUEhjr2Jd2a5Ht5GhLWX0D9NcCNDxnRKeVGJoRIzxRFfRMumaii86sfvXZV8XJYNJa5fXkSwIAyV@MsyRsn6a8j1N5Jj1SJ6p@/P72ma39Pb@R3ZfhAu80wzcbcHv9@PdEVOMABgwkblbjZUfnffCjsLrMTZ@HhIVuHeLA6twITpDzk9BNBDDq6NQD/U@CqAq5jxzzbJ//YOjKof3bf7qDN7egX2ZnKEvh9dogX05mbXtGQAf6qg7VklF6v243vS4gsdusJTiUgNl4thoTAwp1PLDeLT3AjxHTpvn41XdIhmou7j9xqe/AuVnJc3d9Hj/tByjCtrKHNINYU3avFzyxhSe3W/hqOho0bPY88ElUuqvuCK0fB9ClTfoDKGeqEom9WKgdix9tCzPcrh083yoxt3y6YZN0Fb7AzE88GCZuhts/Rm5enV9Ird8uOwJ1lzO8rmH9aTn@KdUHcKBORAt7VlXU3IKreZz@dy3KR7zAgxrLbYZIzqjzBiXP1qH76fiO5uKd1liCu1ol5e8E429bh9W4@ntCLSSeaV3E8l71K6e@tcStUYssSEPXq/KWQF8yPDcUxTTmNkObf2mOeu2ATMwx7z3A2zSn@NQY1rUksX4jP4Wsy/UAQbkk/h@wK@P4NvRAhr0D5TqKht6NdGW160ZGJMU14Lz@mY6IumpKikzxFTUEKUxo3cm5imuZGmuULTXKAZj4BFkikgwVwgyXsBu@e2LnCsUbjBOmMRrtzh6zazDS/XM3w8e72WbKluq0S6kOpgkCVLqh/JYJSloVR/TBOBVD@liXOp/jEkkrElvZPq0bBAAB8uaeIh5nMTjtemVH8kKzcC/f2CiK4m1eM@BZgDdkklcsO2Vwc8iMCLd1UtS2VOpUpQYwL48rBZnZ5K3yX4p6D8WRRQuN0i5RwFxgXIwqSRmjEYHZg2NPo4ennd9FGPtqb4/kayhwLl@VZqUwW1ZEbtkZSRFo0RYwxL6eYjfAODaDfr6zki@srK7C52OHXQUNrJi/Sp9DTqDwxlWt4B4PQmjpPUj/prEQXrwPvxiZU38bnCTkSOcoTBAMoatlCor6VbGoV9vcgL7/10D63uEWAnFiIQ1ksUbcqmgw@HviklNvWmi0pCS/G0z07XwRcflKi9S9WoVeAjc0MxzeYtQ8OQHvzKbc1J1UPWFkwQFnZKPTbK4nmB2mIsSmxdylNlgw9YSNmcIb0n0kK1fcyTFI6ZG5XOFZumoaguI0kt16KZhMoahsjPjJBRT85lMHD@/ZavUU1wwYFHRJCqGVNh9tV7D//dY/575FBHQlgisM6xXj@VrrrXt86yS5w7CdnVDsRClTxW1jpHMYVE5LA6SHnmt@naiouPD2VmTj4jGmNf8vYjscVrgjvktry2YLjQS/AvFjPPcWP2vLxZUKseiXOhRU6LhpQ4HtbwmNOkabfzyhq@rouxBOdo@HrvDvYXOzjdeYiPNsBfEjkb5fiTCfScIh7buKeeOrlgpw4eBp3FTxxJZYK5p@FwcYgWZBz3nz8@/vSTP4FJd29vT1k9isBRC3WTeVy49ZggXraUVbwnnP4OEMZOjD0/3O664ootYcYanAGDntsw9eNjXOG2LGXPl8Yu1GOwKYlyXOfJMDAWrBK6OgZO2TaXawgCsUI5Z3AkkXsL8lbpag1PjVA78ECn36fTV7@PwTn9Pp/FsGviY6QfMvzB8@UkXiP6lZ0ommnDD5nhBsBswn64h2/A8VsqWRxKBn@2Kf4ZtLjWzA3tKNgB94fwiCqOjJArusJ@7SnKYT/KhCG1ZbwDiZSreMcRq4XQuPFJIzU5nW3m6ODjuoKp5/JfbTpnv@xFHx4WRFuvlO2Ze2nQMBBGhd4oleKIBWRF52L0Z288lz6ICn9jyHDZFnIkG5VYZxo98SnXYMlxbk/ZI0Pi0I9AoZUowzRGC2Q8cKwJ/vQM6O6a3eRnNvTK@Il9dgaKVORPwGMBLi/w12gK3qjwKLoVNkM@oz8gxB@ixGPC6FPG@D4wiFNeuJc5IOVd8KZqKkg2eYNgMUyG4P3KJRqkRaHgvQdfeyy5r6bqbstXyuK3Hr0UxLct97Fn37GZAnrHAZV3U3Kmr3fprWl@aEntQOrkMrotX@CPUWjRc0oNY9SmspgRo4cVYJKFTRiOGd3lK@P95XVhy6WGByPAiMlia8DBddFpo8drShzh6pIPSKVMf6cD6FEvlZIFHOxkbwE7lEFVZJZF93EDI34wFD/Aw0RhK4O2kOka1o9UGdP0cUqJLpNtjo4dqOBQZkMguqimLiqw1NhaQ3hbFvOAJS8q4gImgOenH1vM8q5WBaOo/F8)

Languages that should be tested separately:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Morse (73) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><>  (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (I Haven't tested these, but i would be surprised if they don't work)
- DOBELA (109) [local](https://deewiant.iki.fi/projects/dobelx64/)
- ADJUST (113) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/adjust)

### Explanation

ADJUST is a 2D language. The commands are decided by the prime factorisation of the ASCII value of each character it traverses. The commands corresponding to larger factors are executed first. Execution starts in the lower left with the pointer travelling diagonally upward and rightward. Many commands depend on which stack is heavier. The heavier stack is the one with the larger value on top (empty stacks have heaviness -1). The instruction pointer moves forward one cell at the end of every instruction.

commands:

- 2 - rotate accumulator right 3 bits.
- 3 - push accumulator to the lighter stack. If stack 1 was lighter turn 90 degrees anticlockwise. If stack 2 was lighter turn 45 degrees anticlockwise. If both stacks are equally heavy push to stack 1 and turn 45 degrees clockwise.
- 5 - flip bit 0 of the accumulator.
- 7 - move forward once for every bit set in the accumulator.
- 11 - pop heavier stack onto the accumulator. Pops stack 2 if stacks are equally heavy. This is different to what it says on esolangs, but is what is in the code.
- 13 - pop stack 2 and output the value.
- 17 - input a character plus some other stuff.
- 21 - same as 17 but using stack 2 instead of stdin.
- 23 - shift accumulator 5 bits left.
- 29 - does stuff if accumulator is 0, which is never besides right at the start for this program.
- 31 - move one space forward.
- 37 - if lighter stack is defined copy the top value to the heavier stack.
- 41 - if lighter stack is defined discard top of heavier stack.
- 43 - shift accumulator one bit right. Plus some extra stuff if accumulator becomes 0.
- 47 - if lighter stack defined copy it into accumulator.
- 53 - if stack 1 is the lighter stack, reverse bits 0-3 in the accumulator, otherwise, reverse bits 4-7.
- 59 - count the number of bits set in the accumulator and turn 45 clockwise that many times.
- 61 - swap the two stacks entirely.
- 67 - exit the program.
- larger primes - set accumulator to themselves

```
    required values :
    49 (00110001)
    51 (00110011)



    # 35 = 7*5
      nop

      acc(00000001)

      up right

    s 115 = 23*5
      acc(00100000)

      acc(00100001)

      up right

    | 124 = 31*2*2
      up right

      acc(00100100)

      acc(10000100)

      up right

    # 35 = 7*5
      up right*2

      acc(10000101)

      up right

    > 62 = 31*2
      up right

      acc(10110000)

      up right

    $ 36 = 3*3*2*2
      stack 1: 176
      face right 
      right

      stack 2: 176
      face up right
      up right

      acc(00010110)

      acc(11000010)

      up right

    K 75 = 5*5*3
      acc(11000011)

      acc(11000010)

      stack 1: 176 194
      face right
      right

      right

    y 121 = 11*11
      stack 1: 176
      acc(11000010)

      stack 2: 
      acc(10110000)

      right

    7 55 = 11*5
      stack 1: 
      acc(10110000)

      acc(10110001)

      right

    g 103 = 103
      acc(01100111)

      right

    + 43 = 43
      acc(00110011)

      right

    H 72 = 3*3*2*2*2
      stack 1: 51
      face down right
      down right

      stack 2: 51
      face right
      right

      acc(01100110)

      acc(11001100)

      acc(10011001)

      right

    # 35 = 7*5
      right*4

      acc(10011000)

      right

    space 32 = 2*2*2*2*2
      acc(00010011)

      acc(01100010)

      acc(01001100)

      acc(10001001)

      acc(00110001)

      right

    $ 36 = 3*3*2*2
      stack 1: 51 49
      face down right
      down right

      stack 1: 51 49 49
      face up right
      up right

      acc(00100110)

      acc(11000100)

      up right

    ; 59 = 59
      face down

      down

    | 124 = 31*2*2
      down

      acc(10011000)

      acc(00010011)

      down

    = 61 = 61
      stack 1: 51
      stack 2: 51 49 49

      down

    4  52 = 13*2*2
      stack2: 51 49
      output: 1

      acc(01100010)

      acc(01001100)

      down

    ; 59 = 59
      face up right

      up right

    4 52 = 13*2*2
      stack 2: 51
      output: 11

      acc(10001001)

      acc(00110010)

      up right

    ; 59 = 59
      face right

      right

    + 43 = 43
      acc(00011001)

      right

    = 61 = 61
      stack 1: 51
      stack 2: 51

      right

    4 52 = 13*2*2
      stack 2:
      output: 113 

      acc(00100011)

      acc(01100100)

      right

    C  67 = 67
      quit
```

The reason for some of the weird flow was because I couldn't add characters to the line ending with `$$$` because of Minkolang.

#### Incident

I added a space inside the Alice code and a space in the C89 just after the Fortran comment marker for incident.

Answer (score 5):

## 119. [ImageF*ck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ImageFuck), 4295 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOxxxxxxx/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o#B bxe xxxx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                               _      /  _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx@O6O4/x0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0 )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    );b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9 seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjapppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈
♈♈
♈♉
♈
♉♈
♈
♈
♈
♉
♉

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"24 5 10 1 ","O c #FFFFFF","y c #FFFF00 ","t c #FF8000","z c #FF00BC","_ c #0000C0","  c black","x c blue","o c magenta","g c green","r c red","zxxx_Oxxxxx_Oxxxxx_oOxo_","OxxxOOxxxxxOxxxxxxOOO __","tyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy   ","yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOO"};
//}"                       _             _              _             _
main ( ) {puts( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015"" 27""Zingeg-' ?";}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ); print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<(9     >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxxxy"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21#fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002548 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4402 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89,
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C,
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rb3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB/2CRWlvkuIFBO@URK3Fq0SJN5EiKeqytUEQIEGCAASA17V1oufFdvc4Zjztno5229PH3WFHdMTMkycmwhPuiImwX/0V5wfm/MGZzALAi0SttXZ3UyJRqMrKysrKysqqShR6nDH8wx8O8EPXVXk5kFWTNgXDpPu6NBP0IJ1d0p85yYiFIxSFUBl9MJ0IimkcUwc0S0sKL/XhljbVsaBIK0GH6DCt6epA5ya0OeRMWjB4ThMMWp2a2tSkVXF/rghdmKgjKYAZJ5IyAChT0DVdMElylG4pMjfp9blXCbHd0jQdkg06L8i/TH4xaV6dTDilbwBgnM7XsoVy5lX@BF1RdUNALLxgGCrGJen/@h8WBYF/BZqiK5wuqeVM9XwnxWJNXVf7Ux4pN4cCpGNlRUkWDIoHus5ozWZwEAP0Aa0LXN8Co0RVpzELPRnLtETzmkb3ZG4Y5GlZAthiKEkLyBx6BekHtKFOhG0CDFoRhD5taAIviRJPSqWFhSkohqQqRpCW@DE9l2SZ7gsyZNiQwvsBGT01tqKsgoNUX6Vo@PDaK8LXd4cCwCiCU3lBA95g5VVkJXDC4cFc5zQNiAQGNoFwU5qAMEim26AFzpBQ2CCLISh9wjdtLYYqzSnbtaRnEkdzQO9UJ7gNQTehekGClx4KugAoubU0eOa6ZAILkK0Zui5wOn2jC4J3Vyh3ioTCVCzBxIoESbOdnroLtaIbms/KEeQ0kzrQIzfXlxRHB9P04dMJfNMu1wlVqObpL4cPGLbEEJpY0z2cl07/hjaYhwcBvgu2xwz0FwqwUsAVmWZUzWS4gAYEBkwgkOEwiKHALBzU5K2C6dNXbbElVBZUH1qDLil0209qxk91HfvZhqncGCotq8oA@AmV1acK8kOh4yFoAl6FnuKnhRlwTVWsNlLnhMM3QwkazcAm4XrAII5H3lu6gjAUtAXIns1Rp1xDlacEDnIaJgogcAWyIsaSSLdpkZNkzALpiMqiWheMqWxinqnSx5YHdSD0g7RDBq/2EWiizqA4DpCSCOhDk62eR4gCYGgIlVQVk373r/5tfzAAPBmeV/W@La5tuq/yRKtxhFjQFzQKrKpwMiEL4PxYupUdCphxstTnTCxeWdpFECJIqXN1KvdpFQrU5xJ0rSE3g@4oigJvCpaQW6rQT0@4saUvJEtyoeITrgcNSwogZZNqB@jPOWglXqAOiMwEJlNTTNIBrUC7DeYnz6djz6ePDwIQ5w16jw4ZZnACAhc8IlFw5/6a5LQzmwaFsgyTM1SpT2lLc6gqYTrA0y4@rWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q2iHvN4T6Q0HxQlpe9xg4xnoVy394RP8/fS8ePJq9zbJQKWOWLB3ip4eK@LAo1D@sSMmXCSEtSWdDtgh7bSVOMJOY7Jwa1o5MvruJkVcUAGAxRLFeUD1FDQkAVB84SCrBe1BMLtrTYm7KvoKxx2hY@lR5/7wO3brjrBADXdqSj21RtJRa0la8Mp6GhgimJooL11FF2eA@ExUImbMBj76R4Ra6L5QbEQlTgX3LpA90CPOmJEeqTV4zB/APWkjWHTgxy43Q4t9Lf6M@gC6NKm8UYpy@ocCia04bAFGkTBwrkBNBFktiqUsSpklUhidqs2VkCvILaeQCcDPQn6AvY6UO226G/VEcAjYQsGsFl9ZUsFTbglYOGtIXHTb2hJhC41AS2hL2leQNUDOkiwxhUsZEq6oQGGCJokoUA4Ftvtam96mqkzmcAd6OoV89UOhZXf7lOob2hRmNMypwym3ABtIQWycDwvaKatr6Amhgka6fWwQyID9hgaNIbU4efXZZOxxB5dt8pAXW@1nj0icqhkbIMoIINOpTnbmqP7kg7aSV6@Lh0AZq8Kd/2MIDsE/Ox6hwTHEAAhExYCPzVBuYEgz4cSPwTZReoUSz1aY9Hr4iFqu3RQ8AFxXTQSw579GKaCzDoKyXgXRQBb9C0eGGMR1dlOBGn87YivY@aMyR7E6ppEGA@2YoMMFwTZs5kG1lMTLTcYbBxTifSstTm35icwGLo6dFMQlqFpasYx6HbJHE57QWhW5kZflsyagi3LmPpSMlUr3JPVHuhSAzoT45TA8NOetHhVIxK3ZvjIoGZgNIkGnYbR9nkKIuJxiwZoORKfQ@CtJBfRtgSF9esCQAIUBE55RIPozyJogOZS4T2uIJH7IPQQl592YS9zeSGAudZ8yakTVBl0hwzmaJ1ldVAzIqgWW1ETPc3tHZ7WCpvYYm53cKRKiueL@@PHj@5j9xmo448fP0HoFEOfMOSD0CcSCpAQwgUxRHL4SQhT70kOjHt0v9w7mBfeR2y2BQ4lK0nzcPfHx5FHP3fP2tcwXr2gl0ANAXQAL4DH7U2nMej1us7mUNFgT7Rq37A42yfS0BCUASUsNFU36WotX3iqZ24u0i5mauiMLPUYBQbDpwl0N5hwuPbkh5mDkx2CDVU106TBMJ5AFwHInjVRpjqFDgqTBWkimSUyRZEVFO1NozmpOSjXQlDanpCIujpZqxeDEvihSrsOIy40pHemeTjm2qlRTJ3as7yt@ATGT3CSFuSpAc/TAdW6XUfagEkExHlbEGZQ1MDnQ0gyj1tH2pApghInc0G9Z5G/Z3JoA8cRuK/2BHkRjwYEWQyai1UQe2I8SlkXOtB/D2JPXmqx2peBMqFbBRbiqwTOmWDegC4vg@lOlyWDzKO3OU6tZe@Bcll9I7KrpV2blPDGpNpvB7q2sRA5gbYaq6iJNqEnMHpiOyhg@vo2pygZQ/KzA/qGorcpJLcx6YnkZw/AsW1bgKGCE11kySVOk9C8UVWYFM8J2ERVVIsUYJWkcEyDXIIwJO2jZ1fz7xDTE8QpTJ2YnqRg@BtggVSSQIq9nvQeKPAFSXeue8D0aW8f20C4hm@MA3qH8eZUN2Whb1//@x/3oQHeNs@QW4LJz4/XgSfgGzZVQHy3teyseEN@9rcsgRlNZYkjbCChb6HkOZyWcfI6sB81ajs6EBhyOjTu0mlcEE78gZHrK3JmUa4L8rQvONf9hRAW75ogVm5FmpAawRXtKTJEvZP9lQFl5cdprS6rXJ9gsZYbJGHT2la7CAtuAJVjtjQSKKvvoNOxc@jN@gLYCObU@sUlhW@1q6Th92v91YYMxbgeK8BkjOtJ73ARiYi/J9dWd8ExPSDK3NgKPmFwf1WtyujSYAC2jH19DwysTJgIaBwvMHNyeVfFKFNDs5oCQ1/Bp8vW73sgzsLmOvAeIFRTJj@/RuyIIPDQN5BUXNILbLFIesVUmest0e4Z/nr5wQLJ4AnqJc37fKEIjqPrOeBm8VDT3s@PwzTJn0rtz22tMxIEvCqKgvCtPgvjjjTh5EC4vxV8VwU7duImtAd0xM04sCBlzgABMW02CzNoFvLzNaHFoYSfypy@CX1FZDfkOFP992aLmzyaxKuyZEumc/OeLnxtum/Q4Aoy@dlkxbu3/O2DtYzDdGAd2t@hVd7EGds7cvQd6smaLOF0dEswgup7vOPVOX7f7b1DdSZYv/uHrNVeqr5D/QRkIhkwA3ubvc9/S1xx6Y/87OfieC9VJi/vjT@mK6qqw2zZoMPBEBo4ClmvhgFblq0J4U2p9r5MG5KsGnST/H6NF2CVG4b1u1@at9kmcUqAH1p9bB3en20vUWR4ozPk953G5eSBKseTA4aDn3clYKqLqOXt6/dquLWGYtlvaqi1uaMqrH19V7WP4f9bwkFWInWc828Fv2JF7VNn9lzx/QrCjABX3fZXrhhKkpxBxppKvdcAOj@cc0vn@g8YPd7jrjN6aEtiLIM1hxlSSQiYumVA/0NKi369tP736ag3aBPfqsRW445lATQ2@X3TpHQ4xP7KHGwo9P0aS5SnwlTYq0FqvZEAYvM13fH9RIXsahzaiwkMMA83J9dQK3sq@F1U43iOd19VOJwsQSf/pjWzV9VoYGFrOHWuQ6COgbcZB8pU22ncLd41pkrj65wbak7PVvs7RGLKr9VIyW/bTDtmuCGQ734Fcowb6zDhVSdgQyjf0f42UrJOY/3uICYxG8wjCZeA9K/iPabXi4Ngv4I9Aq0qjY0AriN9n@IJvzdTJ8CpFMzFFMFc4u973N6nSHuqKv@a1gF92pfQTAPjE3fpv9VKx3RzOemB5cZvVi6/owWcaSJwC6fE7zZsHVCa34kz8nbh7Suj1NYy3N6Sz1X57PTsG43ewL7LBpPBxFcBneUuxgm80wUJslQw8j3mj@bYtGSREhc2raXMjTfBwSv1oi2BMVI/YPBDYSKQ268Y9Fx/NDWcy7tACxW/e5KDDFmW3NumkmB@g69NU1UE46tApF7OAufeckoTbiAUvyE71joycRJY7yMZftu7AeIk3d7LNtYOIwclhdcFsqvkbFzQB7jXNZ3AJMlU9SBN4DwezufzeikrE9rZAwXAHCiyZY/7eJY3gEHD7McksJJI39/Th18Wx6Fj9oVO065jF/34aGElO0qFhUb22htW1vtD7jF96A4E3IfuB@WYDrkJqCCD2bMXlNuBEyVysejcVJ1WuAnZOsSwU9MTa38SZiPoAjDklL4s0C3ox2SOpurWLpu1lXuDy3L/7e/6tmfEQIBKTiQDhrmBgt486kQYqvNPVrl26RlN49CzAnHMh7juhKUHchnamEsmSC5xiIDJUqt4k7T3V20/I7ipo8LcosJqVFQhuOtvWo1mUdNXBUsq7ILXuZxKwXR0OlHoudQ3h0YQphYKL5D92/WiP4QQTDF1FaXKT5fovoDLIn0kjPQbWVXHZHcCKflvf2ftKkOihCKEYad44lSyVSKNuoBs5fK8OgWqHSQrQVdtEA8yGSbVUxxxQKYFK95L80OObHeDJAaczV4sxtrwzWWadKBAu9EpCnelTiTRc5hpnLfvQ4/p39ATRvjvf8x4v9h8c/0QSLCGy087ICcvKFfbySFI3qS6adfhwmVXC91viLfJWqhsJzkPhklzOZu3E@K5Q@ROmJPNW7JDr@BghC4xigH9A269BLXVadKHnqml/wJNk46h5xjoFg5Clq8PcYLAjUjMcrigf6GHKCsBnmZjIbizGCLj3vcknXUWtSPb@w5MXuhNySrcLBwMR9KkOodPaRgbMKQLfRVdUe5/epg/MobDlYeHxQ@h8ALYpuoA/iODPadQzX85DJ6FfvnFgImGy/XiPrE2YKB7H36pl@qF5k3mptUENr5YtTwoqvqE26gIFAJNhingUJWJcw/wQ5cE49tq4wPRG9QHG9DjoQ85@hRMbxo01Ie1YrHZ6gq4Dq2glUY0yTrtVaKtPkSJtlUdXSetbTes29hWc35HAJB50CenoFcd4kFwvuxRV6Q6LjoNFQpAhQj4muD13b6K7aYSeIvhn/AemG5XYxuKVHUDtR8I62oB23RbMBaReyvx8k9EuQbjyLcpR6hvUQ7A1LdK3yq4mCmVW43C27K3irVh3oCsJWTLn7KwAFMT9KBIJNzyzLLkRrW9gBzFAHp/aPkKcPJGtRn0TDKkniwQSRJRMcvQt7FTkLVwAzs3jXokSGdkAxRpvw@aobc0UbGARg2S3U9rCzSg0K4DYEBwPc75aReFsEb6rTcIKI45mMr8z1bmQwJHMBvUHu@1B4H53b/6t5bH2oMJ4T@xwyKE/6UV/olBBr31urFoXLMG2dIu1WkDRiur4hNusVUnHDBwQJIUmCJLE@DgjDAEwS1iN/Xd4PHct4Gf0AjATNR8qOxIeYL@6EE3jGOGwfF9oMpikOygCQtoB9CVxCvjeYoehKCfmXgsHmUZIDIwcxAGJAthQLMQer3HIELUTNLSP/d4@vT0lHYZMGUS0vETi5HMIfdTxPXzmtBDgKUsU@CehjyQZZMD0s7sbJ5Dzsd6MSv2Qjfrph9PYJS32gUGCg8JAIgXoxWbHy4YiVSbVdDoirAwiVJdOiYO2BcK2Y0XLD9SB1EAEFm40dHttexutmZww3pLmoPbzeDqIFgTwY5d@0Tn/if6wXxQHm1/RxoE5t/vESQFwn@6xwlyLT2Zt@53ntfOc1gb@nNTUXGzrgjU0p4wE44wbNy71VNcNiqgF/vFL4ASegL0LF6QRqpmZHKF0mWt3nzjPkYg3a/B3LT77NT3EAj67x/XAfcrqXeYmi0yzUq26LBym6rNrBchNlPf12TuK@01pe@U3rH2xd6WTRLeFMSGvhcxmTcHimR16C32TSqzBZiz1u3flOrxfnm5fzw9e1AO3hT/yz7P2oPgEQoXhB4M4lfrpvfonJKz23eDzzMYQcdxJOza@I2vPVes@030@05l66cjNq5lzr4iOpaFz2B6O2OUqSxTwXd2HKHuQcYqinhVWYQ59IKucUhlkdRNgTz1ZtdmmxrarsvbBzlsZ5w1k2rW7JB4uHIKTAx0ibegDaKgrTkkcceEWUTJ3Ew8YDKDc1Myv1qSuQSoivUuSF8iu2Wc7ngJrVOawkQK3Dj0oOLYOIqBIkMHqCHUTZZ6J1z6fkGv/Wa@5kMWNDRZMj3ovLUI4hwNauPxYgXYU1lA36/T1KPtaEY7/mA@4lJWnwK/6qpGb@bFecEJNWBqROengBzEQKAvpxOAE8mlIeAoIdBVNQCZgY9uh4h7KMVj1yE46ceg9OBQWPSlAYw0Hq8fVNIPLLtxRuO8PpjPukEPW6w6x@2dbcb8Kge6LY5x91xQUvrCwoOezcePyB2Id887M7fX9UYGiBef7dLXf@3O5ygLzrR77cYV7pVCSKXWimC376RSwaFBoV8TWPdQYtPUyxCEMdQjTjiN9kyJP6RBB2ly63nwKH7D1L104AzHszmt0D4fmRfAhSQEaZJTJCFJxnUjD7r8e5g0tDPGGkofLytJo@/ZYPARwqQQL32IU/ocmBs4GfZSYERClmOCFgZg@DtGiuYwA0KKrOshKZbC@bgOUHuTSUceDEkHBF6QWtNnP9IbbbDpgRZXU6ljuzV21WGKBrE43aMxAO0eNedYnMBf2zkFuIZKDKByMNOTQKF8vhIUBfqrB2RmAr2T5qYgZLrX7zxG5t88ykBKOLBIvLC9XYDQ3UccCu4vsgr2zCFzQqaVJy8w7v/8gAO/aA/9S@aPmCBz8sVzKKeXDBhj3jPP4TDN@iJHPt@hcuQ5VNAc@fFHnI2@HIK18xR0BV0LAAocyt4TkGewjtKHyskhd@o57KfDRyQH3Pp83i@Q4TcGE/xyyL0whz@CNeGHGN3qnZ5Dw4vdIRQMsi9AH/aQQ8YPMvPF46JdC/RUx@IPJZ8PaQgePiEBv2Eemj4yrjw0GTL/PbGNXGYwcdTIrq2ybok3T7ZZDLSjj9caPUa8Fq11zycHePsJhz1p@@yjP/zhgI3DTO9TPOJRP4UjH48O6IPPLubIpbu@PORnJ@57TgwHnx/r43r91vvgcR/kai426oLa/HRCHzHUAXMU@iXBMD///DNYn/T9WfAs@Oi9D7gf7z2Ls0Ti6MQfTx75P/tZt//kgJbZEMt6PeGwl6EfmvRDguOOfNHwZ@VEkiTN6Pfhqw7xeRuwxNIoJR/g42Hrbncs4m7@hC68nz59hD/yD5/1Lf5@JDF2NAF5@/nopT3PC@rg7MPiez9P8K3ZYYZlww84Y4vEP37@AFUWfORzfPyZzGNoVyLpUtXPCEsPD1g2RqsHWbq3EGiMCuCHOuAXi4MVJLIHS/hj8ZM/eDqgDn6TTvu@87NYh4LBJydEHfx8@nP6H/GhDmCWcXB29vjy4gvcB39C5I@@gO/0/vQ0eHa2OAs8nt1TB1@og8ULdRB2gbA8HFEH6cVpg1Bwnz@zaXm2p8BlCJ8GHu@1ermQaRb84dPAQbiYyfnDzVb2gIW72OYWEyN42yhk8rXWjT9s5TovtQutOsQbj09nnz/7gsDGz8GzRyBl8YPvzJc2TZO@ezoK0l//PFkXZh1aJ1AH@bNFiwmcArllO6ZBygk8wN2DF0r7hTq4P7j3fAp/Cofk0CzEjtlxRa1t/ms1iJcWoZGqh4ahIduHhl2EhFZoGVouPtfitSizCE3UGtuHGAH@QhMISiFxERqElJDCsjvo3v@f1NRKTQVUKmQzFyETsYZEuA5qtQogE6H8EfxJoRCSuQjN4D8kE1Fjf3oK0d7QwwN1T7t@FqDvBll3MOQOxt1u6TEW156/vITjz/dkZI@lHu@FhWQ@umi/@@nhPpVKuR9PDhjj4YGx1JkrHHWdIMjLy9NTPnOTeXpicKFjcXro@@wLfIZP@sx3al8@HfTPkK3B048PlNsz73Q6@O3MZ3MrRAJWXGeduH1DAvCZvZN3N7DYLwgez33s8cuL1@v98OA@cVs18XhoAexVj4t9WIRFOuzyEkM2BaMAG0FbIx7znp3FY3AfT3oDnhBJtrI8uDRNe3AFycQ4SPao0@mMrnNLAhSFgejBxelPD6778GM6nYqR6FggFadVPZCKeF1e70/s6aldRtgL0S73wqXqbvrLy/af58vLqYd8vPjn9WKk/Xvm9UCyNwZ3iy@exann1INxEIW5vrycYZDAfYHQvcf76H15seLg1@M9tXCeeYF3OPv/J/xXDdrQaPfBywEaEAodjXk9vaXgjcY9SV/K/kt/hAp4XBF3BOrlcnPu@/vPR5GjRPT@0@PR45Hn9Ch49HD2uKOeve4DGmTZkb00e4B8ow6CJw0XG3a5URZPcBVdlYWgDLP7SOpkVxjcT56j158km/Id@T7fH6VSVtlHR798pGkvoIPCXPA5APmlPfTp2elaqDYovWfw/ULbTIbwyxeQMysN7BGPvVz@8LAIhQj8SS99@OWAezkh6OkXl/tkR1wJeo/7hOyjuL64Djn9nn10vbgOv/Re0G47Yr3EPIhFT06OolY4kTyBYZo9slNCkOK1VixjkCIYHE867skBSpMbWO6FSqV7wkCCIU7b4ZEvFosxYfhd/BAvhBfUCe43WJsbroDL6j90MkXwHdCGkaJgatCDhp/TiRBM/WSZ02lVFD9a8TDHoXuCAGamIMu4UodTALCE5f4cpp0fqQPQM2AAQzJ8JnVOmArCfDqdC@tPTjKOudEIZrD4@f1v//Kfwffv4Ptn1vXP/s9UDH9//9v/9T/@7q//BiL/C3z/H/j@59//9t/8sfUl938P3/93K@7v7e8WnPWlANf/9Pvf/vnf/v63//Kv4Pu/29@/ev393V/8J@v/v9p/GPyb3/3F3@OPdQO4/vJPf/dv/gWQ@BcY/ucQhn87@k/s4FasFfwTJwj5/t0r4D/9/W//9d/a4X@xDbIVD1n/BOL/eiv@TygK2/IjHUv4/cFgEH7w6icfcg0e/uSAsO@PsAdUBdcKU6y1cyphDgjpQgr3ikAE5grZquvh85lT7f1IuGAUBnVpMIQZylxdAxiGAbp/PRa8GRk61AWI3AQfcsKnYU00UmHyGqKCKKDhcCoZS6Yi4aQ/mUpGY2w8FvOzYT@bSCZSIT@Yp0k2noylWH8ymopEo9GUn2bDsVQCJjNKXxIZBowd1uWiSUBSeHzE4BSf1VCDwzPqoC@IMEP8QC88fe@Hg74TQU@TtCuSfAjRLoaBOfCQ048W94/pLzB20jHcemBpl99Vo3n6oEg@cLd07kBDwK1p3SZhQIe7lXUXCmVzcPeEd5AQymEaDXc9mePHEF6Q8FSAoApBdAxQTA7uBnA30KEHQliHMHAb0aK5a9m6zkWtLdQnJA6tYCvONoZrtRr9hEnmcs8Ht5CgEu98nKTBwIkBw8X6uF5OKIZ5cX3dhNt79zrRWjHw0F76CxozHtqQVgLIpCfkn8IAHvs0TbriCdfxEVxdn1wRCC48dMgNKtnlfnC5vPepx0@uRMx1DDOPgPtH9hPY9ynXsSuRcIHKdoVBYGIgDeGEy3UHWkwYBNz0J9fJC4iHI3drwaHB6AkGafjCFADTtbRFjseV8tBE3aUeXNZgYGlWt8ftToTdbq/7BJB8pLdZ4j3BukHVrJo59LmAIqAvBbbLiS6YU13xpAIwstKBlPfkxSLpf9iiSR8fGyan49IBKfKYdsVTLowGkFNPipR1FusdHfvZgP8zZen5OEsdvFB9dFqPpuiT1AnOCMD@OD2zqbuil4mB72KL3hPq0I0UuyM7FtkB@T2kabCtAxE1qh4cHh7CJOTmzBVx1YJPp4w9nThjyDzi4ezEl47mfMQyDzqzlTNi0r/@RKOULuBOcR/P7bAsvGQM@TKgjQNAd@L7h3yCUG4akFInaAS4DjSrNyxx5kc/WLSe/uaAmIB0/YuzEzhVyLLmcQWbjTtukkeD7h9p72@qkvwlGQmckUUADzQTDQ310kz9lPgp@VOlVWvVip9Dx8nj5MPD295AHRi/eNUY@xvl8uTgWHNHou4ITFfSB1Z92YT34CycCBrc8uDRdnHxRBMgPzTcE1MgzB6Ind3PfOdmNiFzOigp@Uf9wUAK/1Hl518OGcbtpmn2MP6bwKn1fwo/uZpVhCsec3nR9cf46eknnNmmaFc4hgLsY2hryN62LzyLI4X8CUcG@ROETYQBt84dpgveI4ZhbsOgzFOpeDJ@QP2BYb62Zg@p60UsURB0YzrZt4qV0aUKhyt8ynolCwKV6UrQ4eocnuFofRrVPi7Tot7fjrOHgq0ocubMbtzSYNAvB2Nh@MXTSciJRLSIKsGD1qpJdnzpIzzxB/2RvNQX6gPgmvImcemBnxOK@oA72HjrceD89I@G6cWdwJCX@vDBUgIAHDTMJ0SOmezIAHtCvVDIHq7fN2hcYCQbe5YTE4d7x6pmuUTKS9rKZBAdag1hxP8Iy90i@IgWLSqgNkc0KZFQjpWziv9ggfWmIpJSLJULkIdO0yJZqLZzu/QePi5OqvdR9NqF0yGIQiwITjhFwBEQ0EGkh@D2TtBTivcQSB/NYrpIFrwBCgZ0P6HET4t2xnu8fYTsiF7kZdUAxFbpHqsG9NGTXaxdB5seUglgIdaO6GMMcPqA99uthw8J3j/C@OP4engwlT6lw961d4KNCxrDOpaJZOQnfUtwyHP4NpsJNvbRD017YjkWeNZwdsyGUS/UkemfnFhNpZ1QVx7e@wUXRE9@M/nxR/4n7X7yeOKdpE28@nwTGB7GHskCOTLTkzSIh3YvPZ6Y9z6f9JieeK88eA8jTzoEwKLFbMNr1w1qrqSBFtw0Mbz@1b0S@I3y6C/eKz4geeo/ukuv/Fw65F/AV0qzftn/nGbtekCZZnrlU064U/ji2uyO8wYMlT7uZNefA7KMPXJ6dc89poEfMmT0@YpQGaDTuJd9vkcvFC5D4tuMJ/KPP3I@@WxxIgcCXoT6KfKpeG9C4NGXxvtjD3e6@LS6n0L@Yw9c01CM7AXiIZ/N65c17UDfCfDYatMN6RaNCyRvAeRN0umju09Hd0fpjx9X94vA5NFvsf84tJEGJH6BxG@oBjE8uvPSr1hCZpAe1w/S8Q/BIwOMLcnnAyb7ta2cFoVHd5CiwXhnU/2C@pKcFuOs@6OE2Y4c1vP95PFjskRBDrUxyEFeZh89yiBvxuAlyQa3XAE1Cax1Dh1X/TDnUwIcgcA0@/QqTHxYfPpEOUXbXgZQMiqXnkBzaPWTw0t0nM@Sk9AMXpfwVK6v69d9atjRuWsTvFm6K9Bg7kfiW92VqCbS4Qydv0cQVANfQi8nlsayfEtA2RDtATBEeyBcALUIMsnWEzZk2k5Ei9NuIMiFekK0HOnx6XUD9ROot03PBxVikQGdeQ8Zkn@UJroJ5EmCEC2dkvIgAF2F@gCVQBqwDtIjfQaKjP7xR9q@PU3DFCaBYwGCIdzIxyLQG0qh8O@gFHAglSOQUdSHpBCg7QOmoEvUTkHRf1xBtluhBzL4Rn7LuzAYvnX5cX/NsLxpkW9eiwxsiw8fRmAh2gTBPzGPIT@kvfzhwB7uj@lcrVJv3RQalUwTftlwNLk5IOt4fZTSmzNZNDxrpScpxP@H5xqs0L3kwX4BYw9ESu3jQWl9@rJVhqlmNe/HZ4KA9eidKZAB9XiNSTDISQtGUNUHzFwaS8zuIYl4qBVxNSLnMQacE66QHDI4yxsf342Lr4EzbhjM7QcZds7YmwiGYR81E3CO2iPHCRJv5wk67UIvtI@mIbu4zkYU2fbEpRw/2UyHSblEzk8bWgh28pNTREwrO@kfFB4p0@dMDiWaSsH89ZgO@THAOoGwE4g4gagTiDmBuBNIOIGkE0jZAdbBzFqY2XAyEolvgolNMLkJptbBaGgT3GCIhjfByCYY3QRjm@CmtOi6tHiS4KUPHG6SrivomMZGk04auugrJomMARr2dWQUCA2/gYTs0TeRUF5yNzKRCtkFlZgaAoXD8c09aB8HNu2xqPJbdPitkq07OxLGKsqa3BCBLeg6aKXCAg@8AqHzHtPog0lRoHZpXhY4MAYEE6yUdBHkX/AeW778@vJ4PUgJiCHNru8huwAzUsjDkrPbLPHZkxzel2xhC@/FZj0LQa8Zs@WEahNpUXm8615KMEZ34raxfkQFixx9ByJsQWAbbKiUt8q80ad7i4x8vcgdhHuLfEOUhTe2LxfyxkOQp52sZPwn2NJOeZadIpDWBjPAPqiTyMCrBsWHOtJf2GPX73/7V/8H/fvf/vnf0L/767/5//7z/4Lh/4Q//xfYLHR4DfBnf44//w5//jf8@Wv8@YutTAQ@cuz63V/9e7j9n/8D/bt/9udW0r/@W5c/ukYEKRi1yfmX/xx//gX@/N8uf2wN@Jd/agFiFpf/hdoxrTwA9Wf/haahNMSyRvZXf0fTLh8YGB5b8u6tPv7o9b5CsGbDPQk9vk63fvmhjmwPeX0uwGvfsZs7HzaAdwu5zuHJk5u@B@aM5fuEWprn@CH6GdtRqoH2D48mjGoEByBv8z4YPfbigBtq/z/Sx7TbhzAQTZ5lSVs63K6/XW/XJhVhfS4GqMPzoWxUGPauKYHpLQXyTWYCSyOI0xYyI2UtGbH5W8WTbZ0BxOVIlmR6WC9ll@XkhkkPbR8QCP@bqS4KLQ5D1rMg5KBOynaZZbcK3FE3r5oNSnkdA1PGjcf6dlYSIUw0aBLItuY3MhZvCBf8r9FtWs7uNoVa8VWHwU8PTMzxtkZaF5SmXa5vwCKnbXgvWlyRXXiLXhvgPnQceaS2fef3Abtub29d1FZcCGVI73sIhq1KWSpjncTuJoW3ksJbSUCzhZPomlg4/IoGMnCgXvS@flpgV0XtZtsIF/Ycpx2QDJgLWuuAflGeGsP0W9REI@8qu7fIt1Cyj2m7nzwoROec0S7vmwyAczdP@nVb7kcdegPztqH250Ru78TstNb7mHbybHUKwj3qNZfWLcem9rXcboFfQc0@@r6zoHDoH1lQ4DsLise@XdDrZsW8O@jf5@@31Y6jJtYafoPM6vgHOwMUDo1/BaK3UUdIsU6CHi9MeTL2lKc3V2nPnsMlIZ5xHgreOVFS33pUGCcxVdUUrOWBz5oKUw4VreCt46P3HeNun9Y8UFRdMLYfYpEsh2DFjQ9I8epAgVHNjw8nS/bZprgHaD2uujuurEc22wrNWSdSI2qLUWh5Pj1JimQ@PYHxKYveDQPxNsijl6abwqOsIbSV37M2bWuaR8VDFUzvt3ESe9fKdiPxY09NsxPdUEiGhgkdL8gw@aKHHD/GQ9kJS7CK5JEStEh7pseLTByqE3UgKCo@HIa5X6EvbXAjQZymEVr8NOen@S2K7Em0h/dzXjvr1a/OSl@FPZx3nT@8i2CHGX5af81j5Ky@p7ind4uzsjnlNX89vc1teptfp1eUdMN8TTOJxNUevP66oiOeDQYA3JAR@TYZfvuZzTfk7JCyjsZDW60M301iXzB4GP6Q0gyAZmzwoAjy4V/fGXC3Jrz9Hv@/3oBO9sL3Nh8xZptL0DeTAtp@ZIpmkAfWFV7wAHjJi7rnbXFr0c5/Z1n2RIfM8Py0iyguBZ19oWNqmqAY6/1VB/E3ZB6dE97IPfFYSFuJe2jSZ356HH6/ifJPfUHmlkLfY0P6t/A6NW4IXJ/oq@@rOCo6ovRU66ReT8jP7phi5KEMAnT8jshw/pnX@75YWSDSWnrIZhyhsPQ@/8jC3WvVjIugaWsPRNVBgx6Qh6HJI@jaUltaD3LJ1mn@th61xh@rJav4fNs3GQJ8sM5qZ/2bYr1fU58Nz7pK3zEirGGDu1XGZzUcjPi0xNs2/HUs@nZNySrDOlPaaeUd6@S9Fpe@1uJbUuHIpGWVfJ9IfkvovlvmtkTNQrZRYblfN4S8wZzjZJnnPdsYrZivtpiqvNEJGIctpirvjCpPexTqOifRdCYeCpm27AsvJUGwBNcZXNtwRYQwB32yBMqpG9q1zpIXSZlw2pbVYsfc82iLbnHRu72PuAVFOWFcyH1Zl8m/Wyb/pkx@p8x1D9gtcguI4neKtFsBm@drTSALovmOdsYknLnD5WtqGz6Kyum49/rFLbmPJT/tnrmPQSG7BfdxwQNK2d13H@dJwHAfN0lg7D6@gsCmb7l/cR873QIBdLglgc8Yb6twvOfdxzmP94Ui73Bxyg26j9dtCjCfrFvCkRdrebVn7/qr61VVQfBbRqWfRokx4KJite4f/eQbgn8Cap8wAokf03T4iADjBGRn0NgaMaxyYNgIkpdEePYNH8fO0pS9vrFZQ4F0X3prUQWlZEr0kfvAvauMLMIwlSw@whUIRL15vJ8imn0zM/sWOXbpIKGkkXfLJ9wLEnug7yHp9wC8vYgjb/I77bWLwmrA76MTM79H5xtynOIIRegM4N1DFjL1Z/dXKoVtvUuL3frbLfR2jQAbMeCAWK1E0G7pdLDh0DYlhWmqtiskJBV3@6TtPPixOyVK76tsRCvYPfOdZBJt1wwVw3bn936tOlv5kLQdFYSJ96FHq5etxwWiizFpo@u2LFWr8wEJWzqnT550FVBs83aQwFnqxk/GiveGISevVSTRXLtqEjIH8dmDKWdapW/2ZfCJhF83fXVyggkONCKCrZzrUiz9qv4K@1217HfHoHaY8KqAfYb1/qH0rXn91VH2FeXypti3DYiJfjrv3WscrUvYsBxmB1uW@ddk7Y2Jj6eEW0a@Vega@ytr32Hbek7wDb69nltYuNBK0Ge7kWNcmB2H32fUW4tEngUdoyWIJdl4rIqvKd1U7eu0WhXf18SYgmM0XH51A@u7DbzdeIiPVEB/xXKrl@OLTMg@xbpv45r61s6FteugopfY@hyZrUhQ98R/be2iBRG1p0a@Vi13YdBNJBLet1sR2Gsh72Ycp766TbCetoT9@KQ/eRca@k4MVd38@KC43rqUkQgwBjiyb2OJn93HvbYu29Lnr/ou5LNgtzhq4xpvugG3o5XQ1OFwyJZsvprAEMH0HHE2Ese8BX77yWwNd41QOnBD5@mJDF9PT@ic8/Rkj2LYNOttpD8c2G9CCG@90Oxg15vpnRdF4gLAdGK9TstegLMflLX8UA7w1XXr10yuc00VU3KcHXB9CLeo1p4Rngjrtd5458RYL6YDSfWEoziFDcfwUS4rF0LjwidxrbTL@WgZOngIm6Gpiv3murH1dkNyJJzhLL0SsqfKnCNuIFYp5Am0LYoshyxnX4y8jIqcKGi9@YtTrCVkhzd@WhgEyY5POAVTjrGkWQfBrF0/DC/JRAgmPlrA454sTPCFUCC7e1aTKxK0yrAoDQYgSIx9OqPl4HKD74gKqGIgt3l1Z5u81ss@Gsv2CSNnx9nrwMBOz84T6gYdjoM1lfIDZzdfYCy6ydD4FHqIOGkRKPgm4JKwgkn/Vt6PnqV398o6Hy/i@@h5wpb9xRopoHVkEHlli8/k88v20rS9aUn0wNbOpXPYAmUfjpEm@5RB9FHTPK4Dl3MEBQYttwlO5p1ntz14asAx9UEhigc9wGje8q0BA1dBo41sr3nXLqkK/QMdCZN3xkB5xEolxQIOa2dvBzukQVYk1vLusxWM64e@6wfcTKQ@HKAutGQN8zuijGFySNZGlumPNjprQwW7stUFnJvY1k0Ephof9hT80ePyARafy@vawQTw9u7HB0vzvs0KStH7B@amH@8U1UwmczNh9cZ5ZpAZZhpduM@Gyr7OKFpgmMKF3M/kS73luZq4mYnh0E33OtuL@OqJ/kKTLia5C61ASdHuxHcXWaQuoqtYLpLL8KFb8bwsRhO5W/HWEDKykGJmo/F1X2hoPVY3pKtqpdpYMcXWdXtwPRLvOp1RQmlSWuMuO7heCNfJjjJrt1Il41po56rmuDoyp@yylujEW3PFyLZvssPLZWk@XpTialeK5a6FRFvULub8MqbxFy3qbnYzjDcvluMUO@kvMzmj3034fEw3lx0kL/j@nXjZzF31B3qsFxs3U1xkNrkUteXw6kJ5Lo9yzRnv00bFUnxGKfXSbC5EO@OefKHcNdrtXj5bn49Z407rj6KdytTsJfV4JDLNCMNRNFaamnqynM1cJcx8ptQuyrdt827ZTtYp88K8SbQu@ZTsm9VMPjLNtxgj1F5cSlfNefwifKNeKJdyaVQfn0/P67I2HeejUu1mEtUHt8WeGg5fXDdnF90ypUcvO91kYxRO5vkFz1zFVHUSuUlVy3plMc0@14ROjm9mhV48lI3dFthRpbbka7Nyo9Gpa53WJGFcsfJdMTSiard8M5MdF8uTJHtTXZaS56XmNJcrLWa9sDhQM9N@J1K5jc/LVaHUuWYiF9zUrPikXE1mRpeXxrLduirdVo076NaVSykqLhfZdlYXn/M5o9IoM1V9PGxGR0pfayeknMpf1ktRszTOXMw7d6lSdiyI9d5YHd905M7UlPIjpkgtc@PrVk@YF6XVnCtEy@1rZlRo8GYiM4g0mZEo9sZyzVgNzsurQXPaG/RTtfNQXni@6mfbsUZBYytFI1pVllT3JitKq8a1yI7rqYvSXa@QkSpKLFcXtPr5xWwRDnclsT6PrdjF7agYlRZ8NFSuZW8rvuvLcMNX9mWzdTVSG1DhfPG8M4hd@dSisGLKIvecyPn06TS6yE/xrWLlliLrk5gcShZvfMOEoXdSlcq8Z5RuG7kOL6@Sd5XxOH7XoG5nJUPVw8nLYibF1Mch/ZwbVUt3CUkpRufZc7mQKnVWraRZKE/l5EV5kL9s6PmbCX@bKgyay@V4kLwU6uVxhhKS@UZj1Bu0e4tu06gvQ5UoP@r5CueF6vMA@nG7WQxftrLxwbQRaV/llVn9puhbqbedsparjtlCPTmN3yQiE2q2uExmmqYiafnzSip@PZXKhUx@0MqxqiDcPvNX7Jhr3ixDSSOhXxdvrzXDZ9701GhvmI0srytdpn1nGLELibpbdOKlzFjnr/oL89JI3ChhtXYdYq/FakuOzTrSc7eujjIT5qp1u2J681VxUTd5szlWY/1EbHy@MJ711ZV@RSW7I05uVXNqecTHr7rSKsHEWOWmmxMrfPcyHMq0BhcVoXgxG6xawiQ8unieXvAcb9Qz3d65HJ8tNJ8YSc7K1E21cztIPD@HekK1m5Iy41ajXjLDNxwz7TbLsedy1zCKfKskZaOSMs1nu@fjSe5uyd0Yi9X0Jt6TxWVdD4cK1KLarbT5kTowisYdP1rdFu@UyjQcv62NxITZH7MTiS23xVCiqjV8eV9dPu8NlvH2VJjxYBlq1yWNzWZGoxpVYyeJWXaZMkzl3Liq9nKXGSmTKSfD11o4cTHOnV8s@lK71a5e9Dk1etfLReK13iAU7merhUE9Ohkk6tVEtJyjbnrL6wbbzycldsjJudHlMqqlyuFsnGnPGxfXo5uhUpVzmc5CzEb4G3We6HCi0hJW8QRTCflGw9SlkglF63GqZebNVrk4j/iUq1IlXF8u@dseN41w4nPX8PHd1XBVawucKg/Lzw32pj0t56TRqB3P8jehWrYZmq6MOaeV61QqX1fYfHkxK86HzU7I0PIXWrK3qPZz9brQ0/oRTezVMgsxNOt07q6vWzVlcns9uWgkerVVnxvF2qbYiNcWJvUMJk97Vm4Ve4u8aIijxuxZOV9Mb9tMtHU@Kbf6M98oddedRaTbWqhczbZFblq6HiTMVnWhVS5lUWYm4dqAoeat@mplChm1UJ1XuguxvVplpKzxzC6uGK58Xsrfmr5UoZjJ126anC7XauflfIabzCvz8m3CJ6yalX5MGj/fUXVFkcP6XVNOZEMRI9yK5Vc5fnQemp5nJzeXNylWY1sX7Urlih3K/IRPdGv5eKfCdzKZy6vlpci163WtftW6oWo@5fbu7oap3cjllFguNW7UWGmmVzqdBDdXM9dcqBSd9OblRXZemU47k9Slr2sKXERdCQLbmMtlRrgA2UlSwnRWz1XrxjL8vBo9D2Z59badymjn8UxuKfZnwmwVyuRnPsYoLub9uKQlwzfdxbnY5SuDwVUjO4xoM@0mnotRlymxorR7uWEltRSuLsrt4tQUmv1eVPIZIW10c51pGS1@KZ3z8eGsZXRl6HyiFrvJ5lKGfJdPXumSL5TksxTfqXB1pjyM3VYv@@o8t6i0l3mYciRZsR6KqUulPU2OlYsrI3vVeb5KJget3sUYCp4O74a81PJl@z3hWpSr1N3tVXtcqE/bzOj6tpKoty58yVVEP3/m1eE5l1rerGqhkCCmBrPSdBHRynzyPHlV4@XLRbXREoVBvBm@ls@VFZVXEsNQRmTns7nC@JaxbLIwELOtqqLnW/xFQlDrHMMsOndmrXObvAqfh65Dzck8FDYqcyYkdhVp2a12u@E@lZ0ZV1qnyc4Kvgsz022OGvy5zFQ7jdJKXZYLYaOVqebEq@l8qZWXkh6548vnObnOSyyYJbH44EZvjVfZWY/qiItyLptM3IUvQIIMQ07Nu1FO4A1tsBgx5cr0Ql6MpuO27pssmIbvrruIpYbtocHw5fJNtTQv6DH10hgpVDzOhy86upYwGs@TZSln5oftlhzNpdqDXu2iy1RuxKvUda55lxBidab0LKQ6zXiIL8c6PMM21MnMhBGJH4yp8jLU13lZ0LnEtPYcK0ynvv5yNjV92l3i/CrZGYxz7IznfJFMT33mFu1LOSRVE8LAqHXms9tiByxEpT1rKVTxrqVFrqQLsXnRrlXGbD3TWJlMNtXhb6ODrs6KijhrRMzYZUkYJHgxX7gbj/IXpedSqCs@h@asrF9fR4oXLJUQfVlT7ctM@1q7VlZhTsh0a8nKvL/KTYZVUbgohfN6txHvN684uQDDqPRcDmnt4nn5rt@Th4yoKrVmIxSi7uLhQue28czO@tf11Y26uNAHl5m6HLkVS4pav22z@WudqSayxevcqHGXWybjdV3uCTeD5I0y8Z1HVJ7LKOU4lRBmQrbdYVqCFGETi1WPGwsMe9cZj5MXzCpurJiMYsxHycEq1TufsJ27qnp@sxwz55PFXT17y04FH8vWeY26Nlf12Pl5x3e1PG@VBnKrJPIMN1mOjIvsVLic967jGV9SC934Cv32cFGuD7ROgUn0ekm2GYl0ouZzv740rqtUO1@@iCTyS3MhFsbT6iJ5oWXizeWidR2Nju9Gi1qyGW/EFuxMHReyWnEQY9RbI6Esbi4GxaxQECuiUVn1@AkVX02rpWKy4IsJXLfevQuJBea52ZfN4UC8ubqNNOMMH7uo1ed3d/kMM0mIo0JJPocxcc5VFsvmqDvuXdeMiESpta6vFF/FV82762pfqXcuK8PefJBI1PWL9ig1XXW1htTwaatWqaee5@sTOb@6BYGLN1KxUUsutDrSbb4RqlFmvJOZgw3OZsvScsCUYqErUQldLibnqdtJJz7ujtu5WaO7GI/izURMnQqrhNl5jk2FVqJ7OWkyfK87H/rC55TaXC1vC9dRvVyda2WzrgpXoWS4fDduTQrTlm@Suyr2zFwnpPXCnfJ86svFwCpIVtqpcLV3NcqWxufXxsV1OEXdFKXlNDk6j5/76jCYTEdGLdmWw/KM6TByez4TxpMQV81zbX3RaxXL/Wo/nGQ0n5SYm1fx58tu/Y4ztajCUMYy3p9zvosCWBB5qRtr@tqmFprAXCR0O4tcKYNI2FBum03ezKmJcSuSEqJFva2o7YU6aoel6/PEeM5LVyMqK6z6UbnV6PSri9W8nxpH@1xz1soUb5VOJKdow4Whs/HUVbjNPdcneqRmavVyi88q1xOOE@e@hZzNV/TmjOoPqpl@p/g8FWftaC0TzSxv@6Ho9G42YpXVbaEbHtV7maE4b3Siq8Y8ku2fs0pjImkTPcyEbtpKYZxctC6EK@pyVRCWw@R1tt6Otq5GqXFEHoyb9dByXJNE/u7OmLKl7qB8zfZLsXb2OjW@EI2MkGilxMsRs6j2anfxXF@IhijfsDRhwrkyH7ks3PrMS16OPUsrtmquUqKyrLakXnMwy2jl/qg1rWYvmCwbnp0vapPIRYOJTLnsJJm/0ru6TAmFWGbRqlXixvAuY7ajaj08S2p3dWlwG@7Xhxw/CcWToIMr/d7dspVpZOflbvWiaWSUwUrw6fMr5bxULGYV6kLsVJ@NZ04Vp5loq1buXj9fZ/TBTaxnGiV28Swwy6VSu8zx/LKbKRnjavuyqZQSoUk/W0lcD/tlpaXWpcgVxacS49sEozT5y2lIiNYz0eJz@5x/Ls3iDXWsmPxN4Y41qw1QdqVYq6Z155NVbhgSF5Fo4daoDfraHfTW0YoKTy8a3X5DHCmLeePSbF9FJk123J7L47jCab5oIVWrcewggpOw2K2qTFT5amDeNquzK51hhqv4VNDOhSuJKoe1QabUiF@GufPzbj7VYifPZSGcrESnmXm41qj4lJig5UuDiRzKjRsj4VqCKUMnXh9dhppVqTW4m@ZuU8smter2xJRy2ZmrV7nxPD@ejW5aiwhMr27aZcNoNm7NfmkW7l0m5F5t2L/JF3PXfI7jjERNyRVqY23a7k3mF9EYNSpGbkeVxKU0iI8TJWHZvZpqqfrlqpQbXkR9XeUyaXY5U36uyaPnas80e88Jqd28vmQ62QSvhJ6XCfN22GEM6iI5KZxHhcSqNGQTLWUym077tYailpb16wqwORGO3Jz3mIzWua6b7f6FwN9etMDSv1SFUvP2Umue3170p32FkiMgvjlGvzovG8Xb/PiOnZcay57E@sa1q3ktloiJqZ5vFptUh9N8LNZJTC6rs2Je0@OLCmj9QX1ZLwuNaoViJ5VuYey7FFk2qVdW7Vm0kRFu473KXJxHY/nMQhkmk63Q4vrynL9O9rTSfNK6ZAfXzPwuNTYmXItrZHhVrFHZZy2yzC/MQihWuIpf3F4Lo/i8X5iGS5l5s1OKm6mq2OlEn@eN@VioFlnxZjGbh@vF2rWpRGOL9vXd@ApaIUbxg8V1ISFUokI/JK3ucnpR7SktLhNiLpnwvNW@9qkD5bkq@Mb1cDGixQuhRZ2DmfFddnrZj/daI7lznr1IDal@lC/4box46S7@fPtckfTbkS8xAZWTFBuz6wqYJD2zdRNdXIupLrtq55IdrldcsYUrJhO9uJimSuHwZTlV7lJGMzYBaXmeh28v83L4ut6@iU59@Wp@0R8271qN3LySvOuyk3qnObvEyViECc3F2qjRWlaLi5YkxAvjRkHMUr7S9dyopTSxkW8XdKbeF4vR0fjivHguTK/46aKg@EKDUms5e55OhORlReYEXSk2zGGGj3ST48iCL2mZ56s2tbzgCpdsLtlO6mOJvxxVW8bImHU0UcpEn2MLn9kY1aWrWL5xc6uMWsNqVedzlXDCEPLj5iR@1xotejOh0L@kRDM14@XFeTVuKtllUbptVa4v@83Qkq8nL6tFfRHqMcXnZmhmMq1ks34z6FV1qTyCgdPXbalqUgaVYg7Va4rThqXQvJ256icHRu48lCxfLmotqeoLXRcao3zYmOk@ZjiphfMrtXAZEeeJQeP6ahLSc7P@0HdVTzB3o6w6r1Ixsx/pcMY41RDZbrfNaIXGyjAqyVbPd3UtM0IjfJfIXqzYm15E60@H3WR3cj577nYrz7128wKa89YnxJuVZ2pwfXVhJMQUz/Zb2Vw5o8600KU@aYjRSVnttsJd0ddd5Evz5/BVqDgq9dhqdbhaZflLvaMk85NeJcctR61km4oUaqH@XUTQLlv5525xOB3xufKCj9yqF4bvNlpdTM/1ZCLORlMzzoi0J5O2L5mRJV8iMlwOw9nCLJ5n@nqjQxVqvlxHVaEXNO7iXJUxov2qbBqtxE2zkGrkirmL8lXhViynmiXu9tbXvS7lCpmb@OXVcBy96rJGlslWhqNmmBqVc@M@Y5rJqdSUikbhXM8vhnfj68m0N0/MykZ3pVxxU2kwYUVOG3fKSiKeuW4/x2qhSKHCFO5WshJOxBYpqs@L/UtGboxvO0mpcMF05SFMoPMg/@PbylTnRd0YpjpQ88pKSeRatUFbv5CHdaBQ7k01XpykpPFQiNxRDaaZLCY68pXI17qNSaLbk25vLiMJcbqA@Ws3v7oS8wy0eqvbHE5Dt/ECmK7R6HOpM5xcz6ptoxHLt2/K9SjVfm7kRbZUKJfbd2afrdZCg@LMbCWSFwWWn2TH1cIy28uW5kW@1bnwjXzhmz4/K7YzcqHd54zF8i6UCukZcUTFR/FKVsyz5jzWFvVo7nJYi3BySV3ULpPapFG/DGcvC9eiOtZD2euM84m3l6mJFFsOxEzmvF3q5gZU5jqXH4XbosE3FN@8RMCyRZn7w68@KkTQdYWAUTNV6tPklY72MRcnXzl4gpw8gY@375w7gc4@2wcJiPbz1UALlON3tfAJ4WOrELK3GcSzmnFr8eT13mKAdY4TIBc8x4M@IuczizsboS4dM6/J@CgpXyOA7HiSHRTcByOPJ/9gHMMXaPA7KIFN5Ik6D@GN95u0EY7gOR8snpH1eLK15elht6lBAqHJOEUEfvpdP@CpCj9CRrIFXKgVvfu29UMnO/mBOENTyEkjrkDQRbLap2Igpl0UVmti/PpsBoocyOJsrH3l7RMcwyZD8RQ534NW/KZ/cp969B/xaRctmBKnTIypPu@PB@pwJtIyrY16C365eqbpWJSOQFnhH2kflsnG0ww5XTABv0k6FbJPZCKfT@RELTyWihz8hofcumk6sD7V6SPtJQE//hy7Tt5IKX00caTQOuRjch9/TCvp0MnkXnk8UXw@r@lLmz7W58GIH1nviTa1PRHvzUfy1D5zRFecR@vxbGb0/VVFuq4q/FB1GzR54dr2Myfk8C2nA004bbs/zQTeVPXtGBHliZvsdMS3UbhLzL3KKakOnLnUBNy6W59KIOObKPHnwzQePXmbjjX88AGP0DixfSe2K/CF0qY9WeKPqQ@En7gFjo/THx/bh8LweKYZbqBhnGRFWrTQkuHB5BMnlVe1pZ1ZskCenLqcbqE88@Deqtf/PZAOVA9k8gnfpKEDmAVisXcHnAbUZGvUa1GF4bKgrPdB8Rwf7wmeckJ/dNKcE38QHuWGnLvzZNISOaUHLqe0DUrOwKC99okTJPZewofeiCvBmdtK@jCaTjSy/xy06LU5gu/eetI4SV/nDBpTfGW3h2aRGZJDNLYABl7wCLQZZwrbTeO0BTq@kYevsD6Ir07OegeCeU7Xl6gb8eEDxNdXSZ4P1svdPLSpWo6VFhl2XlINr93UwDg8@9OtuY9p4gd3AlFkS/RkK3UEqVjXd5InkDzhzOE7yUPEPTXeS9YhGV/59k6yBMnWM5H701VIt3b63wEw0csTxPXJVJ9MTpI91oEeeBTIi6WwPbTP5zB2LQK01TBWe@zmp@2jUeiPVutYwrYjXtA/iVhZACjSHrvz4P1GWkgqHo3qseRiq0yLJ/QX@puF2c6RwOInUhKoXSzfe7SDn94iAPofqFL6bbpTuNXa64ruyE8Qhp0BtjYwK0L/8svXKLMFcVf@2EdH@qwWQj/crRpa3Nrgsd6JtWlXK9PKzrQ/j310zLZ2c3wkNvVwOmV4o0KsvrXp16Kk9KEMQPxxOxpdnrz0p03MvfFIH6@1x4aPVrf4Nh/Db6QHPaJIj/TTvU2Q/36ucij3kJODEbm3URZ4Thh38oadxho6sAt9BtBrbr6SM35HZuxe@msr@321OQD6SKcmvDmxFC0PpuGZTeAe8jirXbd1goXs0H1sxeOrvqRdZNI7yKzz9J4AgXkKNODI5qhxZ0yUlKD1TCro@VA46icu5hbIy4ZNjrL6Hj79E3QuZJw9ZE/x7Se7Konew5o34Ot6I7/OXne5V9WzNP3@yt1bDzW7P7mRRvqtPBGp@wSj5DEdotcHN53QL9/WQ/8wznzZNN@OvWN43tcVTqM7kvg9IvjyDqO/KWS7VQg/0jscn5KXH2vfHJLIIYT7B6WNa/2TE@O4XVp9@10LDKk62U1Hmi2ETgIYytu5/LbNdbZRnfbpi0@mY9z4N1YYed82kQow2U@obXWO07kiGby3Y9dHRxGObKfgk@xoYeoOZZLo2LZgBjv5gvwTNrPFZOQn9OmBqvY9jsFkGwwEg3NCBwD5reOs1maVZV5uiofibKOXHtinfDjj7gnEfLSjyLgCEWh82rKJRBwNSLc5wW6zZd9IBnknHknH0QiKcp4@QGdFS/vQx6/jEXptAn3Ym8nR@HgmGTm50tbzZCTeUQ@uHKegYyg2hzW1PnVh/LohEOYMJtqb8y1JG7zsWWWwzvC0T7f8sj11kU6kINrE60Z3vCC9J2tqTk9dWMxa4F/@cPCRmRo605MURlBmNL7jmjqgBcV6Fcwxvq43kERHYXzbrq1NiF82cUIEMYGWwtKCijD32G/kxVNEXV7KOpOOOC2yFJ7bS/zGZWHWB6vfOrFFU40F@V3CZCEUnGqmSlLsgsjZdfQv0i@b81RD5Ckie8Zgk3NK8GxgPPh8gRW7tHwlA6xlILF4KLF3C8U95iQK1/XgcmH7IaG2P@n9I2UEBY4fIhEoe79Y0yloLiLJL5ThND2etYaswIdXIChbp0xoxHcUiyDWibEk91B9vGcxYMUQF1eUe3ueQhGHYEyRVVVDIUdXUMx/CgywGP@heZMvNBpB@1UAlsc6erlbfsz4iCA5sM5@m7btxove6nhcoNUoH7CyiNsqL71BTvQv4REWa7MJu8Ic2WnxCs8jtGoQYMndm2qs4b0WOGEJedzJvjOQlyH7VA8N7Cjk3SabZytbwMnmAG@x4sM3ucHxPB4EUREmKlCcE2QZiLZ48WHDDgwiR5zyfevyjXss83FNvJUeeJMe2EkPWukWURuoID/UN0DH20Cugy8buBfatQHzvykrTUOlS1VyulRQ1bfoPvkarBGESZq0AT5bN6UlleuE052EwFbKT3ta30r5uJNnLeDr9Hsr3ZbvsN3yayp3YD/vlo9Xym4ggZzBYD@y@EpKg4okW29436QQDUvjsUpWdmxvInZWp7QXRGx1EgA1gW@9xm57lt5g8bGOxiF9xnV2@tkVtJekPnlek2G9wuZNx9rTR7a4RMr0EcYtyEgC5ZDkj1soCE4UNNrpuWdO5qWdebmFFqE@OsVSzkmhux0cqva6i6fRrfsX/HE6@y5xDtzB/sQPFuULq/LWkxa7DCJK96NrP5t2tYmpTwUr0q7UV0aRTdnL1xj3K4mqijNQfkhebu6UKVjPg4jqVOl/XOuJbUXhaIo3fF@n2JzeALCO@L7XhJj4Qv3/)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)

### Explanation

ImageFuck programs are images in which certain colors correspond to brainfuck commands. ImageFuck interpreter traverses image in reading
order, creates bf program based on pixels and executes the bf program. Pixels with unknown colors are ignored.
I used this brainfuck program as the basis:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..++++++++.
```

Piet code contains blue pixels which correspond to `<`. ImageFuck bf interpreter does not allow negative pointer positions, so we jump over `<`s with `[]`:

```
[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..++++++++.
```

[image: magnified image]

ImageFuck uses Python Imaging Library (PIL) to open images. PIL has problems with XPM and, surprisingly, PNG files.
In PIL XPM has at least two problems: polyglot is not recognised as XPM file (even with .xpm file extension) and it does not understand named colors.
PNG files created from XPM with ImageMagick produce error "'int' object is not subscriptable" in ImageFuck.
So I use PPM file as intermediate step (convert.exe is from ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16):

```
convert polyglot.xpm polyglot.ppm
python3 ImageFck.py -i polyglot.ppm
```

ImageFuck interpreter has a bug which prevents it from opening non-square images. I reported [the issue on github](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck/issues/1), 
but it is not resolved yet. So you have to manually fix ImageFuck interpreter as described in the issue to make it work with the polyglot.

Image currently uses 9 colors, which breaks 99. I added red to fix it (red is not used in the image).

I moved `_` that destroyed commas from the second line for DOBELA from line 8 to line 3, it also detokenizes `xxx_` for Incident there.
I thought `x` on line 6 is for DOBELA, but removing it somehow breaks Cardinal, so it stays there.

Fixed Ruby 1.9.3 and Paintfuck, which were broken since answer 117.

Comment: That `x` was for DOBELA, I don't know how it affected cardinal

Comment: These recent graphics-based languages are making the VIP score slip :(

Comment: Not being recognized as an XPM image is likely due to us not including `/* XPM */` (based on my testing with Gimp. Most things that read XPM's seem to want that there

Answer (score 5):

## 126. [Nhohnhehr](https://github.com/catseye/Nhohnhehr), 4717 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#11111D#_#x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _       x _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00@O6O4/m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL

You can see a y and a x here. <
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x[]={"23 7 12 1 ",
"z c #0C8302",
"b c #B87A63",
"_ c #0000C0",
"d c #708FB7",
"e c #58007B",
"f c #FFC0FF",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"y c #FFFF00","c c black","g c green","x c blue","o c magenta",
"fceyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz",
"fcbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdObOOOO",
"fcggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO",
"fcccccccccccccccccccccc",
"fffoOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_",
"fffOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOc__"};//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002358 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 4830 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgndKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQB4kai11u5uSiQKVVlZWVlZWVlViUKPM4Z/@MMBfuiaKi8HsmrSpmCYdF@XZoIepLNL@jMnGbFwhKIQKqMPphNBMY1j6oBmaVpSeKkP97SpjgVFWgk6xIdpWtPVgc5NaHPImbRg8JwmGLQ6NbWpSavi/mwRmi5M1JEUwJwTSRkAmCnomi6YJD1K0y1F5ia9PvcqJfaqQE2HdIPOC/Ivk19MmlcnE07pGwAZp@l8NVsoZ15hSND0taobAuLhBcNQMTJJ04uCwL8CTQEop0tqOVM5f5XEhuhzIJ3TZGFBcz3D1DnelFTF4l1NV/tTHutlDgXIibwQJVkwKB5oPqM1uwWCGKAPaF3g@hYYJao6jVnoyVimJZrXNLonc8MgT8sSwBZDSVpA1tErSD@gDXUibJNm0Iog9GlDE3hJlHhSKi0sTEExgDojSEv8mJ5Lskz3BRkybEjh/YCMnhpbUVbBQaqvUjR8eO0V4eu7QwFgFMGpvKAB17DyKjIZOOHwYK5zmgZEAgMbQLgpTUBWJNNt0AJnSCiNkMUQlD7hm7aWU5XmlO1a0jOJozmgd6oT3IagI/ODBC89FHQBUHJrSfHMdckEFiBbM3RN4HS6qQuCd1dmd4qEwlQswcSKBEmznZ66C9WiG5rPyhHkNJM60CPNm0uKo4Np@vDpBL5pl@uEKlTy9JfDBwxbIgpNrOkezkunf0MbzMODAN8F22MG@gsFWCngikwzqmYyXEADAgMmEMhwGMRQYBYOavJWwfTpq7bYEioLqg@tQZcUuu0nNeOnuo7dcMNUbgyVllVlAPyEyupTBfmh0PEQNAGvQi/y08IMuKYqVhupc8Lh5lCCRjOwSbYE31ImhKGgTkD2bI465RqqPCVwkNMwUQCBK5AVMZZEuk2LnCRjFkhHVBbVumBMZRPzTJU@tjwoC6EfpB0yeLWPQBN1BsVxgJREQB@abPU8QhQAQ0OopKqY9Lt//e/6gwHgyfC8qvdtcW3TfZUnao8jxIIuoVFgVYWTCVkA58fSrexQwIyTpT5nYvHK0i6CEEFKnatTuU@rUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITc0pR@esKNLX0hWZILFZ9wPWhYUgApm1Q7QH/OQSvxAnVAZCYwmZpikg5oBdptMD95Ph17Pn18EIA4b9B7dMgwgxMQuOARiYI799ckp53Z0mSgXEzOUKU@pS3NoaqE6QBPu/i0qgmKx72Dw@136z23N4h6zOM9kdJ8UJSUvscNMp6Fct3eEz7N30vHjyevcm@XCFjmiAV7q@DhvS4KNA7pEzNmwklKUFvS7YAd2kpTjSfkOCYHt6KRL6/jZlbEARkoUCxVlA9QQ0FDFgTNEwqyXtQSCLe32piwr6KvcNgVPpYefe4Dt2@76gQD1HSnothXm5KKWkvWhlPQ0cAUxdBAe@soujwHwmOgEjdhtPbTPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dYHugR51xIj0SKvHYf4A6kkbw6YHOXC7HVrob/Vn0AXQpU3jjVKW1TkUTGjDYQs0iIKFcwNoIshsVShjVcgqkcTsVm2sgF5BbD2BTgZ6EvQF7HWg2m3R36ojgEfCFgxgs/rKlgqacEvAwltD4qbf0JIIXWoCWkJf0ryAqgd0kGCNK1jIlHRDA@wUtFhCgXAsttvV3vQ0U2cygTvQ1Svmqx0KK5/ZsQ5gABKFOS1zymDKDdBUUiALx/OCZtr6CmpimKCRXg87JDJgj6FBY0gdfn5dNhlL7NF1qwzU9Vbr2SMih0rGNpYCMuhUmrPNPbov6aCd5OXr0gFg9qpw188IskPAz653SHAMARAyYSHwUxOUGwjyfCjxQ5BdpE6x1KM1Fr0uHqK2SwcFHxDXRSMx7NmPYSrIrKOQjHdRBLBF3@KBMRZRne1EkMbfjvg6Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNshwQZA9m2lgPTXQcoPBxjGVSM9am3NrfgKDoatDNwVhGZqmZhyDbpfM4bQXhGZlmvqyZFYVbFnG1JeSqVrhnqz2QJca0JkYpwSGn/akxasakbg1w0cGNQOjSTToNIy2z1MQEY9bNEDLkfgcAm8luYi2JSisXxcAEqAgcMojGkR/FkEDNJYK73EFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLTp2gyqA7ZDBH6yyrg5oRQbXYiproaW7v8LRW2MQWc7uDI1VSPF/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75d7BvPA@YrMtcChZSZqHuz8@jjz6uXvWvobx6gW9BGoIoAN4ATxubzqNQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbpJV6r5wlMt07xIu5ipoTOy1GMUGAyfJtDdYMLh2pMfZg5OdgjWVdVMkwbDeAJdBCB7RkWZ6hQ6KEwWpIlklsgURVZQtDeN5qTmoFwLQWl7QiLq6mStXgxK4Icq7TqMuNCQ3pkE4phrp0YxdWpPAbfiExg/welbkKcGPE8HVOt2HWkDJhEQp3RBmEFRA58PIckUbx1pQ6YISpzmBfWeE/mFDb1g/HqOt6XEtzHuS38/E@HNnkmpXWgcS@yrPUFexKMBQRaD5mIVxG4ej1LWhQ7034PYk5darPZloEzos4GF@CqB0ymLwiYMFGWYF9BlySBz@O3mpNaC/UC5rI4X2R0CXJuU8MZe229kuraxECEEQRirqOY2oSewqGI7KGBu/DanKBlD8rMD@oaitykktzHpieRnD8CxbbiAFYSzaGTJJc7B0HZSVZhxzwnYRFVUixRglaRwTJ1cgjDe7aNnd1jZIaYniFOYlzE9ScHwN8ACqSSBFHs96T1Q4AuS7lz3gOnT3j62gXAN31ge9A7jzaluykLfvv63P@5DA7xtniG3hPkEP14HnoBv2FQB8d3WsrPiDfnZ37IEZjSVJY6wgYS@hZLncM7HyevAftSoSulAYMjp0LhLp3FBOPEHhsWvyJlFuS7I077gXPcXQli8a99YuRVpQmoEVzTWyPj3TvZX1pmVH@fMuqxyfYLFWsuQhE1rW@0iLLgBVI7Z0kigCb@DTseIojeLF2CAmFPrF9crvtWukobfr/VXGzIU43qsADM9rie9w0UkIv6eXFvdBQ2GgChzYyv4hMH9VbUqo0uDARhK9vU9MDBhYZahcbzAzMnlXRWjTA3NagoMfQWfLlu/74E4i6rrwHuAUE2Z/PwasSOCwEPfQFJxvTCwxSLpFVNlrrdEo2r46@UHCyTjKKiXNO/zhSI4pK4nmJuVSU17Pz/aACR/KrU/t7WISRDwqigKwrf6LIw70oSTA@H@VvBdFewYoZvQHtARN@PAPJU5AwTEtNkszKBZyM/XhBaHEn4qc/om9BWR3ZDjrCO8NxXd5NEkXpUlWzKdm/d04et5wQYNLk@Tn01WvHvL3z6Y4jhMB9ah/R1a5U2cDr4jR9@hnqyZGM51twQjqL7HO16d4/fd3jtUZ4L1u3/IWu2l6jvUT0AmkgHTu7fZ@/y3xBXXFcnPfi6O91Jl8vLe@GP6WlV1mIobdDgYQgNHIYvhMGDLsjXbbJaq78u0IcmqQTfI79d4ASa/YVi/@6V5m20SpwT4odXH1uH92fYSRYY3OkN@32lcTh6ocjw5YDj4eVcCprqIWt6@fq@GW2solv2mhlqbO6rC2td3VfsY/r8lHGSZU8cFha3gV6yoferMnoi@X0GYEeCS3v7KFUNJkjPIWPO09xpA54dzbulc/xGjx3vcdUYPbUmMZbDmMEMqCQFTtwzof0xp0a@X1v8@HfUGbeJbldhq3LEsgMYmv2@alA6H2F@Zgw2Fvl9jifJUmAp7NUi1NxJAbL6mO76fqJBdjUN7pYIB5uHO5xpqZU8Fv4tqHM/x7qsKh5Ml6OTftGb2qhoNLGwNp841CNQw8DbjQJlqO427xbv6VKl/nXNDzenZan@HSEz5tRop@W2baccMNwTy3a9AjnFPHya86gRsCOU72t9GShaBrN8dxCRmg3kk4fqS/lW8x/R65RHsV7BHoFWlsRHARarvUzzh92bqBDiVgrmYIphL/H2P2/sUaU9V5V/TOqBP@xKaaWB8ogvAt1rpmG4sJz2w3PjNsuh3tIAzTQRu4ZT43YatAUrzO3FG3q7qfWWU2lrj21vyuSqfnZ59o9Hr2HfZYDKY@Cqgs9zFOIF3uiBBlgpGvsf80RyblqyA4qqptU66cVU4eKVetCUwRuoHDH4oTARy@xWDnuuPpoZzeRdooeJ3T3KQIWuee9tUEsxv8LVhqopgfBWI1MtZPd1bTmnCDYTiN2Vns4SAu4O8Lu0E9y8mHFvCzkO2bygGa2KnKmNhaTjX/ebvkocmnE6@im1ft@VxpfKb/TTI7F0x/oYVpwzVoTIUhjpj6Pzmbm@fsdf7iTPHer/P8NteKBAn6bbPgbF27DkoKbwukN0/Z4OJPsA9yekE5pumqgdpAufxcD6f10tZmXDKMlAAzIEirhW432p5bRg0TCRNAiuJ9P09ffhlcRw6Zl/oNO06dtGPjxZWsvNXWGjEJ6JuZb0/5B7Th@5AwH3oflCO6ZCbgAoyWJB7QbkdOFEiF4vOTdVphZuQLV4MOzU9sfaRYWKHrhpDTunLAt0ClUimu6pu7YZaW@5NXOH8r3/ftz1YBgJUciIZYDEMFPS6UifCUJ1/ssq1S89oGoceMIhjPsQlPCw9kMvQxlwyQQkQxxWYd7aKzaS9D277g8FNDfvFFhVWo6I2Ru8M02o0i5q@Klgyaxe8zuVUCmb204lCz6W@OTSCMEtTeIHss683ZyCEYIqpqyjzfrpE9wVcYeojYUQFyao6JrtISMl//Xtr9x8SJRQhDDvFE@efrRJpVKtky53n1SlQ7SBZCbpqg3iQydAnpjh4Q48TrHgvzQ854pYAkhhwNuWxGGtjPpdp0IEC7UbnNdw9PJFEz2Gmft6@Dz2mf0NPGOG//THj/WLzzfVDIMEaLj/tgJy8oFxtJ4cgeZPqpl2HC5ddLXSTIl5Ba6GyfR09GCbN5WyyT4iHFZE7YU422YknhYJdHl2XFAP6B9x6CWqr06QPPVNrKAk0TDqGHn6gpjkIWT5ZxFkFN4wxy@GC/oUeoqwEeJqNheDOYoiMPgqTdNbZH4hsb@EweaE3JQuas3AwHEmT6hw@pWGYxZAu9FV0Gbr/6WERDgUeFonCI2M4zHl4WPwQCt8C91Qdcv3IYAcqVPJfDoNnoV9@MWDq5nK9uE@sLS3o5YdfaqVaodHMNFsN4OaLVdmDoqpPuI2mQFnQZJhUD1WZ@GIBW3RJML6tPT4Q9UF9sAE9HvqQo0/RPxMUFYld6xibw66A69AKWumg77fzbTJ@2M31JpshbCW@SrU1kCjRtraka0RgbNlwG9ua0u/IEPIfuvUUVLNTcdyM3KPxCCtcdBqYEQBmUDsVXd@9ZsgmZQ1rNdQnEgGtZdfBAdnDm20cH16j2IcB2LSBeAuALFoXhdW10q267a37yz9DhTUYvf4RFd6pMcHx1RojxNdqDIBO7AcrRzFTKrfqhd1MIEwb99rCAswGULci6UGWo54lW6rtFOboHxhehpbrCCdvNKhBzyRD6skCkTYR9b8MKgQ7Hdm9MFCH0KiugnRGNkBf9/uggHpLE/UXKO4g2a@2Nq0DCu06AGYF18Opn3ZRCGuk3zoHgX6aw@SG/9nKfEjgCGaD2uPM@CAwv/vX/85yYHwwIfyndliE8L@ywj8xyKC3TlgWjWvWIFvapRptwKBoVXzCLbbqhOMSjnuSMhVoaQIcnBGGILhF7Ka@Gzye@zbwExoBmIkKFnUqKU/QHz3olXPMMGhGDFRZDJI9T2EB7QAqmTjpPE/RoRSGASYei0dZBogMzByEAclCGNAshF7vMcgaNZO09M89nj49PaVdBkxyhXT8xGIkc8j9FHH9vCb0EGApy@K4pyEPZNnkgLQzO5vnkPOxXsyKXc7NuunHEzAmrHaB8chDAgDixWjF5ocLBjzVZhU0uiIsTKK0l44lBWaMQpwzBMut2EEUAEQWbvR7fC27m800dDHYkubgdjO4OgjWQLBj1z7Ruf@JfjAflEfb/ZUGgfkPewRJgfCf7fGJXUtP5q03pue1LyXWhv7cUFTcXi0CtbQnzIQjDBv3bvUUl40K6MV@8QughJ4APYsXpJGqGZlcoXRZrTXeeBMSSPdrMDftPjv1PQSC/vvHdcD9SuodpmaLTOM6W3RYuU3VZp0CITaLFa/J3Ffaa0rfKb1j7WS@LZskvCmIDX0vYjL5CxTJet5b7JtUZgswZ@20vCnV4/3ycv94evagHLwp/pd9jtYHwSMULgg9GMTN2k3v0TklZ3@2iU@/GEHH1Sfs2jxGsHZksu430e/7GK6fpdl4Gjo7wehnGD5j@sKMUaayTAXf2SOGugcZqyjiZGcR5tALusYhlUVSNwXy1Jt9tm1qaLsubx/7sX2z1kyqWpNQ4vDMKTD/0CXegjaIgramqsQ7FyYrJXMzv4E5E64mkGnckkxZQFWs9636EplTc7rjNLZOaQgTKdB06EHFsfEbBEWG/nBDqJss9U649P2CXns6fc2lMGhosmR60JdvEcSpINTG48UKsKeygK6Ap6lH2@@QdtwDfcTDsDYFftVUjd5Mv/OCE6rDDIzOTwE5iIFAX04nACeSS13AUUKgK2oAMgMf3Q4R91CKx65DcNKPQenBobDoSwMYaTxeP6ikH1h245vIeX0wbXaDHrZYdY4bctuM@VX@lFsc4@65oKT0hYUHHd2PH5E7EO@ed2Zur@uNDBCnTtvDs//au9NRFpxp99qNZ@QrhZBKrRXBbt9JpYJDg0JPNJg9QIkNUy9DEMZQjzjhNNozJe6xBh2kya3nwaP4DVP30oEzHM/mtEL7fGTeAReSEKRJTpGEJBkXoDz4BIiHSUM7Y6yh9PGykjT6ng0GHyFMCvHSh7hykANzA@fcXgoMTshyTNDCAAx/x0jRHGZYSJF1PSTFUjjt1wFqbzLpyIMh6YDAC1Jr@uxHeqMNNj3Q4moqdWy3xq46TNEgFqd7NAag3aPmHIsT@Gu7EwHXUIkBVA4mlBIolM9XgqJAf/WAzEygd9LcFIRM9/qdxw79mydbSAkHFokXtn8SELr7xEvB/UVWwZ45ZE7I7PXkBcb9nx9w4BftoX/J/BETZE6@eA7l9JIBY8x75jkcpllf5MjnO1SOPIcKmiM//oiT3pdDsHaegq6gawFAgUPZewLyDNZR@lA5OeROPYf9dPiI5IBbn8/7BTL8xmCCXw65F@bwR7Am/BCjW73Tc2h4sTuEgkH2BejDHnLI@EFmvnhctIs8NIjFH0o@H9IQPHxCAn7DPDR8ZFx5aDBkfn1iG7nMYOKokV1bZd0Sbx6CtBhoRx@vNXqM@JlaK9VPDvD2Ay970vbZR3/4wwEbh0nUp3jEo34KRz4eHdAHn13MkUt3fXnIz07c95wYDj4/1sa12q33weM@yFVdbNQFtfnphD5iqAPmKPRLgmF@/vlnsD7p@7PgWfDRex9wP957FmeJxNGJP5488n/2s27/yQEtsyGW9XrCYS9DPzTohwTHHfmi4c/KiSRJmtHvw1cd4uNXYImlUUo@wMfD1tzuWMTd@Ak9uj99@gh/5B8@61v8/Uhi7GgC8vbz0Ut7nhfUwdmHxfd@nuBbzZJgm2HZ8APO2CLxj58/QJUFH/kcH38m8xjalUi6VPUzAtPDA5aN0eoBjHwLge7Ri0UAP9QBv1gcrCCRPVjCH4uf/MHTwYKmDn6TTvu@87NYh4LBJydEHfx8@nP6n/ChDmCecXB29vjy4gvcB39C5I@@gO/0/vQ0eHa2OAs8nt1TB1@og8ULdRB2gbg8HFEH6cVpnVBwnz@zaXm2Z8ZlCJ8GHu9rZTB@m/7waeAgXMzk/OFGK3vAwl1sc4uJEbytFzL5aguga@VCplE4L7ULrRrEG49PZ58/@4LAx8/Bs0egZPGD78yXNk2Tvns6CtJf/TzZ18U65CRQB/mzRYsJnAKxZTumTooJPMDdgxcK@4U6uD@493wKfwqH5NAsxI7Z8bVa3fxXqxAvLUIjVQ8NQ0O2Dw27CAmt0DK0XIQmapXtQ1CAv9DnarwaZSYQIYXERWgQUkIKy@5ge/9/UlWvqyogVCGbuQiZiDskwnVQrV4DMhGKH8GfFAohlYvQDP5DMpE09qenkDf08EDd066fBei5QdYdDLmDcbdbeozFtecvL@H48z0Z12Opx3thIZmPLtrvfnq4T6VS7seTA8Z4eGAsZeYKR10nCPLy8vSUzzQzT08MLnMsTg99n32Bz/BJn/lO7cung/4ZMjV4@vGBcnvmnU4Hv535bG6FSMCK66wTt29IAD6zd/LuBhb7xcDjuY89fnnxer0fHtwnbqsmHg8tgLXqcbEPi7BIh11eYsamYAxgI2hpxGPes7N4DO7jSW/AEyLJVpYHl6ZpD64gmRYHiU9BOp3RdW5JgKIwDD24OP3pwXUffkynUzESHQuk4rSqB1IRr8vr/Yk9PbXLCHsh2uVeuFTdTX952f7zfHk59ZCPF/@8Xoy0f8@8Hkj2xuBu8cWzOPWcejAOojDXl5czDBK4LxC693gfvS8vVhz8erynFs4zL/AO5/7/jP@qQRsa7T54OUDzQaGjMa@ntxS80bgn6UvZf@mPUAGPK@KOQL1cbs59f//5KHKUiN5/ejx6PPKcHgWPHs4ed5Sz131Agyw7spdmD5Bv1EHwpO5iwy43yuIJLtWrshCUYW4fSZ3sCoP7yXP0@pNkU74j3@f7o1TKKvvo6JePNO0FdFCYCz4HIL@0hz49O10L1Qal9wy@X2ibyRB@@QJyZqWBNeKxF@MfHhahEIGnT3rpwy8H3MsJwU@/uNwnO/JK8HvcJ2S3xvXFdcjp9@yj68V1@KX3gmbbEesl1kEsenJyFLXCieQJjNLskZ0SghSvtbAZgxTB4HjSc08OUJzcwHMv1CrdEwYSjHDaDpN8sViMCcPv4od4IbygTnBXw9pCcQVcVgeikymC74A2jBQFM4MetPycToRg/JNlTqdVUfxoxcMUh@4JAliZgizjQh3OAMAQlvtzmHV@pA5A0YD9awjwmdQ4YSoI8@l0Lqw/Ock45ka0ZwQzWPz8/rd/9S/g@/fw/XPr@uf/RyqGv7//7f/8v/3ub/4WIv8LfP9v@P7n3//23/6x9SX3/wDf/2cr7h/s7xac9aUA1//w@9/@xd/9/rf/6q/h@7/a379@/f3dX/4n6///tf8w@Le/@8t/wB/rBnD91Z/97t/@CZD4lxj@lxCGfzv6TyFI@wLWx7eVTv9yCBqdpR9@2UT@Kf0Lw4Kip5l1JGD99788oPMVa0E6OH9hQixEW5B/9vvf/pu/g9gdyD9xsn@mIe41pC0OTkF/CpB/s0OnDfmnVIJu1eCnXjq/aG5dm4VM7oKK09lqJf/qErOBYnS5UGyubxNWqpM1tkbRLZTLr2/tC9VVpzTPoXwJNEdbWpiDYR@PlgjSp9RZo9CE6GaVTibX9wu8j4TJfa2F96UKvSS3t3it1dqGy6VSKPsf6VjC7w8Gg/CDVz/5kGvw8CcHhH3fHjmgrnFpNcVa@9kS5oCQLqRwBw@6zFwhG6g9fLp5qr0fCReMwqAuDYYwoZurawDDMGCwXA@eb4bSDnUBXXSCjwjis@Qm2vQw1w9RQezQ4XAqGUumIuGkP5lKRmNsPBbzs2E/m0gmUiE/WPNJNp6MpVh/MpqKRKPRlJ9mw7FUAuZ@Sl8SGQYsQ9bloklAUnh8huYUH0ZSg8Mz6qAviDCh/kAvPH3vh4O@E0FPk7QrknwI0S6GcVG483G0uH9Mf3GFI3QCSqBZ2uWnXCuapw9CuWQkFMbbHt5mk4lMPIK3TyQVPrkQ3vbxNhFKFrMJvBXwNpYMhRJZvBXxtljMhYpFvK1at/jB26VzGwJULh7uejLHjyE8gPBAB00G4QWJnwoQVCGIbjOKyRHsvLB8@1lZSb3vSqouq/1qrwofK2kwcFIG1fXHStr7IUmiqAKUNalR8fpUXahPdlLVSbKu1Sr/9OR6OcEWQFmglx7vF2IUemhDWgkgq56QfwqWUOzTNOmKJ1zHR3B1fXJFILjw0CE3jG0u94PL5b1PPX5yJWKuY5jABdw/sp9gmpRyHbsSCRftPXGFQZBiLlecDidcrjsYDoRBwE1/cp3ogjnVFTp88oIUrNKhE0IJ/ezBK@fH3573iw3WO3nBFSIg89mz8vn88PV@QorBpAMr1Xu8hEHUe/ICwuhI@VpMabBJg0EavjA/w3QtbVXS40p5aDIYpR5c9lhtzeI9bnci7HZ73SeA5CPt2urb3hNCCG0xzOPU2gX1hFqnwLS0q@ZJBcDwoQMpIMsi6b/bokkfHxsmp@O6DinymHbFUy6MBpDTlFXWWax3dOxnA/7PlDUKx1nq4IXq4zMg0RR9kjrByRqYh6dnNnVX9DIx8F1s0XtCHbqRYndkx2A@IL@HqO4PAhE1qh4cHh7C/LB55oq4qsGnU8ae6Z0xZIr3cHbiS0dzPjJtCjoTyTOcFr/5RKOULqCbQB/P2LEM8GQM@TKgjQNAd@L7x3yCUG4akFInaKO5DjQUaF5e4rScfrBoPf3NAbHQ6doXZ0N3qpA15@NrbDbuuEGetLt/pL2/qUjyl2QkcEZWaFB6aGiol0bqp8RPyZ@uW9VWtfg5dJw8Tj48vJ1tfgZlKNUL1IHxi1eNsb9RLk8OjjV3JOqOwJQyfWBVm014D87CiaDBLQ8ebW8nTzSBogb3xF4Ls/SB2Nn9zHduZhMy7Yaikn/UHwyk8B9d//zLIcO43TTNHsZ/Ezi1/k/hJ1e1ynDFYy4vuoEZPz399HRAg9lFu8IxlGQfQ1uG1bYZ6FkcKeRPODLInyBsIgy4de4wXfAeMQzTDsMYkkrFk/ED6g8M87WdFUhdLzWKgqAb08m@tcaMLl1zuA6rrNcbIXA9XQk6XJ0Tb5zBhsbRBhfTcbjZjrNHoK0oclDUbtzSYNBJC2MpCkMSOWGMFlE3eHBWYZJ9efoIj@lC5zQv9YX6ALimvEn8u@DnhKI@oE8C3nocOD/9o2F6cb825KU@fLA1mGEGDfMJkWMmOzLAnlAvFLKH6/cNGpeByfar5dHG4Q6/qlmuxvKStjIZREVbIydxRsNytwg@okWLCqjNEU1KJJRj5aziP1hgvamIpBRL5QLkodO0SLYT7NwuvYdnPJDqfRS9duF0CKIQC4ITThFwBAR0EOkhuL0TdJvjPQTSR7OYLpJtCYACO8JPKPHTop3xHm8fITuiF3lZNQCxVbrHqgF99GQXa9fBGRiwEsBCrB1RzGT00Ae83249fPj2/tFLf3G8djyYSp/SYe/a6cPGBY1hnaVGMvKTviU45PAMm80EG/voh6Y9sdw/PGs4O2bDqBfqyPRPTqym0k6oKw/v/YLL1ie/mfz4I/@Tdj95PPFO0iZefb4JjBNjj2SBHJnpSRrEQ7uXHk/Me59PekxPvFcevIchCIbLF0q0mG147bpBzZU00IJbW4bXv7pXAr9RHv3Fe8UHJE/9R3fplZ9Lh/wL@Epp1i/7n9OsXQ8o00yvfMoJdwpfXEHfcc@BMdPHnexEYZaxR06v7rnHNPBDhow@XxEqA3Qa97LP9@iFwmVIfJvxRP7xR84nny1O5EDAi1A/RT4V700IPPrSeH/s4U4Xn1b3U8h/7IFrGoqRvUA85LN5/bKmHeg7AR5bbboh3aJxgeQtgLxJOn109@no7ij98ePqfhGYPPot9h@HNtKAxC@Q@JMt1yXP0Z2XfsUSMtP3uH6Qjn8IHhlgtkpgmRzd@bWtnBaFR3eQosHAZ1P9gvqSHPHk7M6ghNnuNtahHOSxfjK3ISdRGeT0PbOP7oWQN2PwkmSDW36hmgSTBA4dwv0wNVcCHIHANPvIOUx8WHz6RDlF274gUDIqlx5OpmCyQU4c0nHZgRxfaLl4f0u/7lPDjs5dW/6N0l2BhllGJL7VXYlqIh3O0Pl7BEE18CX0cmJpLMsDCJQN0R4AQ7QHwgVQiyCTbD1hQ6btRGgtp4EgF@oJ0fJDx1MhDNRPoN42PR9UiEUGdOY9ZEj@UZroJpAnCUK0dErKgwB0FeoDVAJpwDpIj/QZKDL6xx9p@/Y0DfOaBI4FCIZwIx@LQG8ohcK/g1LAgVSOQEZRH5JCgLYPmIJ@azsFRf9pBdnOpR7I4Bv5LR/TIPEx9UwVw3KtRr55LTKwLT58GIGpaBME/8ROhvyQ9vKHA3u4P6Zz1WuYiBfq15kG/IIVn9ycane8Pv/szUFKGh6Q1JMU4qXFc3VW6F7yYL@A1QcipfbxdMM@fdkqwwy3kvfjs3bA@gNrtQAG1OM1JsEgJ5gYQVUfMHNpLDG7557iSXTEIYycshpwjqVDcsjgLG8cvjf@3gZO9GEwtx8Q2jkYcyIYhn0@VMA5H5OcAUpc3yfowQ290D5Piuy1O9uFZHMaV9z8xOVBlwYSOfRwaCHYyU@O/jGt7KR/UHgOVJ8zOZRoKgXz4mM65McA6wTCTiDiBKJOIOYE4k4g4QSSTiBlB1gHM2thZsPJSCS@CSY2weQmmFoHo6FNcIMhGt4EI5tgdBOMbYKb0qLr0uJJgpc@cLhJuq6gYxobTTpp@DSJYpLIGKBhX0dGgdDwG0jIHn0TCeUldyMTqZBdUImpIlA4HN/cg/ZxYNMeiyq/RYffKtm6syNhrKKsWQ4R2IKug1YqLPCUOhA67zGNrq0UBWqX5mWBA2NAMMFKSRdB/gXvsfVgh7483njFIoY0u76H7AJMTSEPSw5ctMRnT3J4X7KFLbwXm/XYDr1mzJZvsE2kReXxzkhrYYzuxG1j/YgKFjn6DkTYgsA22HUmdsps6tO9RUa@XuQOwr1FviHKwhvblwt54yHI005WMv4TbGmnPMtOEUhrgxlgn65LZOBVg@ITPukv7LHr97/96/@d/v1v/@Jv6d/9zd/@f//5f8Lwf8Kf/xNsFjq8Bvjzv8Cff48//wv@/A3@/OVWJgIfOXb97q//A9z@j/@R/t2/@Asr6d/8ncsfXSOCFIza5Pyrf4k/f4I//5fLH1sD/tWfWYCYxeV/oXZMKw9A/fl/oWkoDbGskf3139O0ywcGhseWvHurjz96va8QrNlwT0KPr9OtX36oI9tDXp8L8Np37ObOhw3g3UKuc3hc7KbvgTljeaihluY5foje4HaUaqD9w6MJoxrBAcjbvA9Gj7084Iba//f0Me32IQxEkweb0pYOt@tv19u1SUVYn4sB6vBQNxsVhr1rSmB6S4F8k5nA0gjitIXMSFlLRmz@VvA4amcAcTmSJZke1kvZZTm5YdJD26d6wv9mqotCi8OQ9WAQOV2Xsh2b2a0Cd9TNq2aDUl7HwJRx8xDBdlYSIUw0aBLItuY3MhZvCBf8r9FtWs7uNoVq8VWHwU8PTMzxtkZaF5SmXa5vwCKnbXgvWlyRXXiLXhvgPnQcedx5JGEfsOv29tZFbcWFUIb0vodg2KqUpTLWSexuUngrKbyVBDRbOImuiYXDr2ggAwfqRe9OvJVtS0XtZtsIF/Ycpx2QDJgLWguCflGeGsP0W9REI@8qu7fIt1Cyj2m7nzwoROec0S7vmwyAczdP@nVb7kcdegPztqH250Ru78TstNb7mHbybHUKwj3qNZfWLcem9rXcboFfQc0@@r6zoHDon1hQ4DsLise@XdDrZsW8O@jf5@@31Y6jJtYafoPM6vgHOwMUDo1/DaK3UUdIsU6CHi9MeTL2lKc3V2nPnhNhIZ5xHrbfOQZW33oEHycxFdUUrOWBz5oKUw4VreCtM9/3vZjBPmJ9oKi6YGw/aiRZbtuKGx9149WBAqOaHx/6l@wDiXHr0XqyendcWY9sthWas46RR9QWo9DyfHqSFMl8egLjUxa9GwbibZBHX1o3hefPQ2grv2dt2lY1j4qHlZjeb@Mk9q6VrSnxY09VsxPdUEiGhgkdL8gw@aKHHD/GNykQlmAVyYM/aJH2TI8XmThUJ@pAUFR8zA9zv0Jf2uBGgjhNI7T4ac5P81sU2ZNoD@/nvHbWq1@dlb4KezjvOn94F8EOM/y0/prHyFl9T3FP7xZnZXPKa/x6ehvb9Da@Tq8o6Yb5mmYSias9eP11RUc8GwwAuCEj8m0y/PYDvG/I2SFlHY0nLVsZvpvEvmDwMPwhpRkAzdjgQRHkw7@@M@BuTXj7Pf5/vQGd7IXvbT5izDaWoG8mBbT9yBTNIGcrKLzgAfCSF3XP2@LWop3/zrLsiQ6Z4flpF1FcCrpkQ8fUNEEx1hutDuJvyDz6RLyRe@IokbYS99Ckz/z0OPx@E@Wf@oLMLYW@x4b0b@F1alwXuD7RV99XcVR0ROmp1vHanpCf3THFyKMzBOj4HZHh/DOv932xskCktfSQzThCYel9/pGFu9eqGRdB09YeiKqDBj0gT8aT8wi0pba0HreTrVdw2HrUGn@slqzgU4jfZAjwwXrBAuvfFOv9mvqse9ZV@o4RYQ0b3K0yPlHjYMRnWt624a9j0bdrSlYZ1pnSTivvWCfvtbj0tRbfkgpHJi2r5PtE8ltC990ytyVqFrKNCsv9uiHkDeYcJ8s879nGaMV8tcVU5Y1OwDhsMVV5Z1R52qNQ1zmJpjPxsNW0ZV94KQmCJbjO4NqGKyKEOeiTJVBO3dCudZa8SMqE07asFjvmnkdbdIuL3u19xC0oygnjQu7Lukz@3TL5N2XyO2Wue8BukVtAFL9TpN0K2DxfawJZEM13tDMm4cwdLl9T2/BRVE7Hvdcvbsl9LPlp98x9DArZLbiPCx5Qyu6@@zhPAob7uEECY/fxFQQ2fcv9i/vY6RYIoMMtCXzGeFuF4z3vPs55vC8UefGSU27QfbxuU4D5ZN0SjrxYy6s9e9dfXa@qCoLfMir9NEqMARcVq3X/6CffEPwTUPu4GUj8mKbDRwQYJyA7g8bWiGGVA8NGkLzZxbNv@Dh2lqbs9Y3NGgqk@9JbiyooJVOij9wH7l1lZBGGqWTxEa5AIOrN4/0U0eybmdm3yLFLBwkljbxbPuFekNgDfQ9Jvwfg7UUceZPfaa9dFFYDfh@dmPk9Ot@Q4xRHKEJnAO8espCpP7u/Uils611a7NbfbqG3awTYiAEHxGolgnZLp4MNh7YpKUxTtV0hIam42ydt58GP3SlRel9lI1rB7pnvJJNou2aoGLY7v/dr1dnKh6TtqCBMvA89Wr1sPS4QXYxJG123ZalanQ9I2NI5ffI8soBim7eDBM5SN34yVrw3DDl5rSKJ5tpVk5A5iM@ITDnTKn2zL4NPjvy66auTE0xwoBERbOVcl2LpV/VX2O@qZb87BrXDhFcF7DOs9w@lb83rr46yryiXN8W@bUBM9NN5717jaF3ChuUwO9iyzL8ma29MfDx93zLyrULX2F9Z@w7b1nOCb/Dt9dzCwoVWgj7bjRzjwuw4/D6j3lok8izoGC1BLMnGY1V8Temmal@n1ar4vibGFByj4fKrG1jfbeDtxkN8pAL6K5ZbvRzfPkT2KdZ9G9fUt3YurF0HFb3E1kf0bEWCuif@a2sXLYioPtXz1Uq5C4NuIpHwvt2KwF4LeTfjOPXVbYL1tCXsx/MYyAsM0XdiqOrmxwfF9daljESAMcCRfRtL/Ow@7rV12ZY@f9V3IZ8Fu8VRG9d40w24Ha2Epg6HQ7Zk89UEhgim54izkTjmLfDbT2ZruGuE0oEbOk9PZPh6ekLnnKcnexTDpllvI/3hwH7DSHjrLYQHu95M77z5FRcAphPrHXj2Apz9OLPlh3KA75tcvzd2nWuqmJLj7IDrQ7hFtfaM8ERYr/WaSifGepskSKonHMUpbDiGj9xZuRAaFz6Ja6VdzkfL0MET@QxNVezXTY6tV5KS8wENZ@mVkD1V5hxxA7FKIU8KblFkOWQ5@2LkDXLkpE7rdX2cYi0hO7zx08IgSHZ8wimYcowlzTquZ@36YXhJJkIw8dECHvdkYYJvcQPZ3bOafC1BqwyL0mAAgsTYp55aDi5NfLFbQBUDuc27eNvkXXz2IWe2Txg5SNBeBwZ2enbOETDocBysqZQfOLv5AmPRTYbGswJCxEmLQME3AZeEFUz6t/J@9Cy9u1fW@XgR30fPE7as9VySBK0jg8grW3y2H1faWpq2Ny2JHtjauXSOxKDsI0zSZJ8yiD5qmsd14HIOCsGg5TbBybzzhL0Hz3Y4pj4oRPGgBxjNW741YOAqaLSR7TXv2iVVoX@gI2HyLiYoj1ippFjAYe3s7WCHNMiKxFrefbaCcf3Qd/2Am4nUhwPUhZasYX5HlDFMDjzbyDL90UZnbahgV7a6gHMT27qJwFTjw56CP3pcPsDic3ldO5gA3t79@GBp3rdZQSl6/8A0@/FOUc1kMs0Jq9fPM4PMMFPvwn02VPZ1RtECwxQu5H4mX@otz9VEcyaGQ83uTbYX8dUS/YUmXUxyF1qBkqLdie8uskhdRFexXCSX4UO34nlZjCZyt@KtIWRkIcXMRuObvlDXeqxuSFeV60p9xRRbN@3BzUi863RGCaVBafW77OBmIdwkO8qs3UqVjBuhnauY48rInLLLaqITb80VI9tuZoeXy9J8vCjF1a4Uy90IibaoXcz5ZUzjL1rU3aw5jDculuMUO@kvMzmj3034fEw3lx0kL/j@nXjZyF31B3qsFxs3UlxkNrkUteXw6kJ5Lo9yjRnv00bFUnxGKbXSbC5EO@OefKHc1dvtXj5bm49Z407rj6Kd66nZS@rxSGSaEYajaKw0NfVkOZu5Spj5TKldlG/b5t2ynaxR5oXZTLQu@ZTsm1VNPjLNtxgj1F5cSleNefwi3FQvlEu5NKqNz6fnNVmbjvNRqdqcRPXBbbGnhsMXN43ZRbdM6dHLTjdZH4WTeX7BM1cxVZ1EmqlKWb9eTLPPVaGT4xtZoRcPZWO3BXZ0XV3y1Vm5Xu/UtE5rkjCuWPmuGBpR1Vu@kcmOi@VJkm1WlqXkeakxzeVKi1kvLA7UzLTfiVzfxuflilDq3DCRC25qXvukXFVmRpeXxrLduirdVow76NbXl1JUXC6y7awuPudzxnW9zFT08bARHSl9rZ2Qcip/WStFzdI4czHv3KVK2bEg1npjddzsyJ2pKeVHTJFa5sY3rZ4wL0qrOVeIlts3zKhQ581EZhBpMCNR7I3lqrEanJdXg8a0N@inquehvPB81c@2Y/WCxl4XjWhFWVLdZlaUVvUbkR3XUhelu14hI10rsVxN0GrnF7NFONyVxNo8tmIXt6NiVFrw0VC5mr299t1chuu@si@bramR6oAK54vnnUHsyqcWhRVTFrnnRM6nT6fRRX6KrwIstxRZn8TkULLY9A0Tht5JXV/Pe0bptp7r8PIqeXc9Hsfv6tTtrGSoejh5WcykmNo4pJ9zo0rpLiEpxeg8ey4XUqXOqpU0C@WpnLwoD/KXdT3fnPC3qcKgsVyOB8lLoVYeZyghma/XR71Bu7foNozaMnQd5Uc9X@G8UHkeQD9uN4rhy1Y2PpjWI@2rvDKrNYu@lXrbKWu5ypgt1JLTeDMRmVCzxWUy0zAVScufX6fiN1OpXMjkB60cqwrC7TN/xY65RnMZShoJ/aZ4e6MZPrPZU6O9YTayvLnuMu07w4hdSNTdohMvZcY6f9VfmJdGoqmE1epNiL0RKy05NutIz92aOspMmKvW7YrpzVfFRc3kzcZYjfUTsfH5wnjWV1f6FZXsjji5Vcmp5REfv@pKqwQTY5VmNyde893LcCjTGlxcC8WL2WDVEibh0cXz9ILneKOW6fbO5fhsofnESHJWppqVzu0g8fwc6gmVbkrKjFv1WskMNzlm2m2UY8/lrmEU@VZJykYlZZrPds/Hk9zdkmsai9W0Ge/J4rKmh0MFalHpXrf5kTowisYdP1rdFu@U62k4flsdiQmzP2YnEltui6FERav78r6afN4bLOPtqTDjwTLUbkoam82MRlWqyk4Ss@wyZZjKuXFV6eUuM1ImU06Gb7Rw4mKcO79Y9KV2q1256HNq9K6Xi8SrvUEo3M9WCoNadDJI1CqJaDlHNXvLmzrbzycldsjJudHlMqqlyuFsnGnP6xc3o@ZQqci5TGchZiN8U50nOpyotIRVPMFch3yjYepSyYSitTjVMvNmq1ycR3zKVek6XFsu@dseN41w4nPX8PHd1XBVbQucKg/Lz3W22Z6Wc9Jo1I5n@Waomm2EpitjzmnlGpXK1xQ2X17MivNhoxMytPyFluwtKv1crSb0tH5EE3vVzEIMzTqdu5ubVlWZ3N5MLuqJXnXV50axtinW49WFST2DydOelVvF3iIvGuKoPntWzhfT2zYTbZ1Pyq3@zDdK3XVnEem2GipXsm2Rm5ZuBgmzVVlo15eyKDOTcHXAUPNWbbUyhYxaqMyvuwuxvVplpKzxzC6uGK58Xsrfmr5UoZjJV5sNTper1fNyPsNN5tfz8m3CJ6wa1/2YNH6@o2qKIof1u4acyIYiRrgVy69y/Og8ND3PTpqXzRSrsa2L9vX1FTuU@Qmf6Fbz8c4138lkLq@WlyLXrtW02lWrSVV9yu3dXZOpNuVySiyX6k01Vprp151OgpurmRsuVIpOevPyIju/nk47k9Slr2sKXERdCQJbn8tlRrgA2UlSwnRWy1VqxjL8vBo9D2Z59badymjn8UxuKfZnwmwVyuRnPsYoLub9uKQlw83u4lzs8teDwVU9O4xoM60Zz8Woy5R4rbR7ueF1ailcXZTbxakpNPq9qOQzQtqoeZNpGS1@KZ3z8eGsZXRl6HyiFmtmcylDvssnr3TJF0ryWYrvXHM1pjyM3VYu@@o8t7huL/Mw5UiyYi0UU5dKe5ocKxdXRvaq83yVTA5avYsxFDwd3g15qeXL9nvCjShXqLvbq/a4UJu2mdHN7XWi1rrwJVcR/fyZV4fnXGrZXFVDIUFMDWal6SKilfnkefKqysuXi0q9JQqDeCN8I58rKyqvJIahjMjOZ3OF8S1j2WRhIGZbFUXPt/iLhKDWOIZZdO7Mauc2eRU@D92EGpN5KGxcz5mQ2FWkZbfS7Yb7VHZmXGmdBjsr@C7MTLcxqvPnMlPp1EsrdVkuhI1WppITr6bzpVZeSnrkji@f5@QaL7FglsTig6beGq@ysx7VERflXDaZuAtfgAQZhpyad6OcwBvaYDFiytfTC3kxmo7bum@yYOq@u@4ilhq2hwbDl8vNSmle0GPqpTFSqHicD190dC1h1J8ny1LOzA/bLTmaS7UHvepFl7luilepm1zjLiHEakzpWUh1GvEQX451eIatq5OZCSMSPxhT5WWor/OyoHOJafU5VphOff3lbGr6tLvE@VWyMxjn2BnP@SKZnvrMLdqXckiqJISBUe3MZ7fFDliISnvWUqjiXUuLXEkXYuOiXb0es7VMfWUy2VSHv40OujorKuKsHjFjlyVhkODFfOFuPMpflJ5Loa74HJqzsn5zEylesFRC9GVNtS8z7RvtRlmFOSHTrSav5/1VbjKsiMJFKZzXu/V4v3HFyQUYRqXnckhrF8/Ld/2ePGREVak26qEQdRcPFzq39Wd21r@prZrq4kIfXGZqcuRWLClq7bbN5m90ppLIFm9yo/pdbpmM13S5JzQHyaYy8Z1HVJ7LKOU4lRBmQrbdYVqCFGETi1WPGwsMe9cZj5MXzCpurJiMYsxHycEq1TufsJ27inreXI6Z88nirpa9ZaeCj2VrvEbdmKta7Py847tanrdKA7lVEnmGmyxHxkV2KlzOezfxjC@phZq@Qr89XJRrA61TYBK9XpJtRCKdqPncry2NmwrVzpcvIon80lyIhfG0skheaJl4Y7lo3USj47vRoppsxOuxBTtTx4WsVhzEGPXWSCiL5sWgmBUK4rVoXK96/ISKr6aVUjFZ8MUErlvr3oXEAvPc6MvmcCA2r24jjTjDxy6qtfndXT7DTBLiqFCSz2FMnHPXi2Vj1B33bqpGRKLUatdXiq/iq8bdTaWv1DqX18PefJBI1PSL9ig1XXW1ulT3aatWqaee52sTOb@6BYGL11OxUUsutDrSbb4eqlJmvJOZgw3OZsvScsCUYqErUQldLibnqdtJJz7ujtu5Wb27GI/ijURMnQqrhNl5jk2FVqJ7OWkwfK87H/rC55TaWC1vCzdRvVyZa2WzpgpXoWS4fDduTQrTlm@Suyr2zFwnpPXCnfJ86svFwCpIXrdT4UrvapQtjc9vjIubcIpqFqXlNDk6j5/7ajCYTEdGNdmWw/KM6TByez4TxpMQV8lzbX3RaxXL/Uo/nGQ0n5SYm1fx58tu7Y4ztajCUMYy3p9zvosCWBB5qRtr@NqmFprAXCR0O4tcKYNI2FBuGw3ezKmJcSuSEqJFva2o7YU6aoelm/PEeM5LVyMqK6z6UblV7/Qri9W8nxpH@1xj1soUb5VOJKdow4Whs/HUVbjNPdcmeqRqarVyi88qNxOOE@e@hZzNX@uNGdUfVDL9TvF5Ks7a0Wommlne9kPR6d1sxCqr20I3PKr1MkNxXu9EV/V5JNs/Z5X6RNImepgJNdtKYZxctC6EK@pyVRCWw@RNttaOtq5GqXFEHowbtdByXJVE/u7OmLKl7qB8w/ZLsXb2JjW@EI2MkGilxMsRs6j0qnfxXF@IhijfsDRhwrkyH7ks3PrMS16OPUsrtmKuUqKyrLSkXmMwy2jl/qg1rWQvmCwbnp0vqpPIRZ2JTLnsJJm/0ru6TAmFWGbRql7HjeFdxmxH1Vp4ltTuatLgNtyvDTl@EoonQQdf93t3y1amnp2Xu5WLhpFRBivBp8@vlPNSsZhVqAuxU3k2njlVnGairWq5e/N8k9EHzVjPNErs4llglkulepnj@WU3UzLGlfZlQyklQpN@9jpxM@yXlZZakyJXFJ9KjG8TjNLgL6chIVrLRIvP7XP@uTSL19WxYvLNwh1rVuqg7EqxVlXrzier3DAkLiLRwq1RHfS1O@itoxUVnl7Uu/26OFIW8/ql2b6KTBrsuD2Xx3GF03zRQqpa5dhBBCdhsVtVmajy1cC8bVRmVzrDDFfxqaCdC1cSVQ5rg0ypHr8Mc@fn3XyqxU6ey0I4eR2dZubhav3ap8QELV8aTORQblwfCTcSTBk68droMtSoSK3B3TR3m1o2qFW3J6aUy85cvcqN5/nxbNRsLSIwvWq2y4bRqN@a/dIs3LtMyL3qsN/MF3M3fI7jjERVyRWqY23a7k3mF9EYNSpGbkfXiUtpEB8nSsKyezXVUrXLVSk3vIj6uspl0uxypvxclUfPlZ5p9p4TUrtxc8l0sgleCT0vE@btsMMY1EVyUjiPColVacgmWspkNp32q3VFLS1rN9fA5kQ40jzvMRmtc1Mz2/0Lgb@9aIGlf6kKpcbtpdY4v73oT/sKJUdAfHOMfnVeNoq3@fEdOy/Vlz2J9Y2rV/NqLBETUz3fLDapDKf5WKyTmFxWZsW8pscX16D1B7VlrSzUK9cUO7nuFsa@S5Flk/r1qj2L1jPCbbx3PRfn0Vg@s1CGyWQrtLi5POdvkj2tNJ@0LtnBDTO/S42NCdfi6hleFatU9lmLLPMLsxCKFa7iF7c3wig@7xem4VJm3uiU4maqInY60ed5fT4WKkVWbC5m83CtWL0xlWhs0b65G19BK8QofrC4KSSE66jQD0mru5xeVHtKi8uEmEsmPG@1b3zqQHmuCL5xLVyMaPFCaFHjYGZ8l51e9uO91kjunGcvUkOqH@ULvqYRL93Fn2@fryX9duRLTEDlJMX67OYaTJKe2WpGFzdiqsuu2rlkh@sVV2zhislELy6mqVI4fFlOlbuU0YhNQFqe5@Hby7wcvqm1m9GpL1/JL/rDxl2rnptfJ@@67KTWacwucTIWYUJzsTqqt5aV4qIlCfHCuF4Qs5SvdDM3qilNrOfbBZ2p9cVidDS@OC@eC9MrfrooKL7QoNRazp6nEyF5eS1zgq4U6@Yww0e6yXFkwZe0zPNVm1pecIVLNpdsJ/WxxF@OKi1jZMw6mihlos@xhc@sj2rSVSxfb94qo9awUtH53HU4YQj5cWMSv2uNFr2ZUOhfUqKZmvHy4rwSN5Xssijdtq5vLvuN0JKvJS8rRX0R6jHF50ZoZjKtZKPWHPQqulQewcDp67ZUNSmDSjGH6g3FacNSaN7OXPWTAyN3HkqWLxfVllTxhW4K9VE@bMx0HzOcVMP5lVq4jIjzxKB@czUJ6blZf@i7qiWYu1FWnVeomNmPdDhjnKqLbLfbZrRCfWUY18lWz3d1IzNCPXyXyF6s2GYvovWnw26yOzmfPXe718@9duMCmvPWJ8Qb18/U4ObqwkiIKZ7tt7K5ckadaaFLfVIXo5Oy2m2Fu6Kvu8iX5s/hq1BxVOqxlcpwtcryl3pHSeYnvesctxy1km0qUqiG@ncRQbts5Z@7xeF0xOfKCz5yq14YvttoZTE915OJOBtNzTgj0p5M2r5kRpZ8ichwOQxnC7N4nunr9Q5VqPpyHVWFXlC/i3MVxoj2K7JptBLNRiFVzxVzF@Wrwq1YTjVK3O2tr3tTyhUyzfjl1XAcveqyRpbJXg9HjTA1KufGfcY0k1OpIRWNwrmeXwzvxjeTaW@emJWN7kq54qbSYMKKnDbulJVEPHPTfo5VQ5HCNVO4W8lKOBFbpKg@L/YvGbk@vu0kpcIF05WHMIHOg/yPb6@nOi/qxjDVgZpfr5RErlUdtPULeVgDCuXeVOPFSUoaD4XIHVVnGslioiNfiXy1W58kuj3ptnkZSYjTBcxfu/nVlZhnoNVb3cZwGrqNF8B0jUafS53h5GZWaRv1WL7dLNeiVPu5nhfZUqFcbt@ZfbZSDQ2KM7OVSF4UWH6SHVcKy2wvW5oX@VbnwjfyhZt9flZsZ@RCu88Zi@VdKBXSM@KIio/i11kxz5rzWFvUo7nLYTXCySV1Ub1MapN67TKcvSzciOpYD2VvMs4n3l6mJlJsORAzmfN2qZsbUJmbXH4UbosGX1d88xIByxZl7g@/@qgQQdcVAkbNVKlPk1el2sdcnHzl4Aly8gQ@3r5z7gQ6@2wfJCDaz1cDLVCO39XCJ4SPrULI3mYQT9TGrcWT13uLAdY5ToBc8BwP@oicoi3ubIS6dMy8JuOjpHyNALLjSXZQcB@MPJ78g3EMX6DB76AENpEn6jyEN95v0kY4gud84Fl2oceTrS1PD7tNDRIITcYpIvDT7/oBT1X4ETKSLeBCtejdt60fOtnJD8QZmkJOGnEFgi6S1T4VAzHtorBaE@PXZzNQ5EAWZ2PtK@8I4Rg2GYqnyPketOI3/ZP71KP/iE@7aMGUOGViTPV5fzxQhzORlmlt1Fvwy9UzTceidATKCv9I@7BMNp5myCGQCfhN0qmQfTQT@Xwip9ni@VTkvDk8ithN04H18U4faS8J@PHn2HXyRkrpo4kjhdYhH5P7@GNaSYdOJvfK44ni83lNX9r0sT4PRvzIek@0qe2JeG8@kqf2mSP62nm0Hk/QRt9fVaRrqsIPVbdBkxcZbj9zQk7hcjrQhNO2@9NM4E1V344RUZ64yU5HfBuFu8Tcq5yS6sCZS03Arbv1qQQyvuEVfz5M49GTt@lYww8f8AiNE9t3YrsCXyht2pMl/pj6QPiJW@D4OP3xsX0oDE@j3H74QOIkK9KihZYMDyafOKm8qi3tzJIF8uTU5XQL5ZkH91a9/u@BdKB6IJNP@L4THcAsEIu9O@A0oCZbo16LKgyXBWW9D4rn@HhP8JQT@qOT5pz4g/AoN@TcnSeTlsgpPXA5pW1QcgYG7bVPnCCx9xI@9EZcCc7cVtKH0XSikf3noEWvzRF8EduTxkn6OmfQmOLrFz00i8yQHKKxBTDwgmehzThT2G4apy3Q8Y08fIX1QXw1ciI/EMxzur5E3YgPHyC@vkryfLDe9OehTdVyrLTIsPOSanjtpgbG4RGtbs19TBM/uBOIIluiJ1upI0jFur6TPIHkCWcO30keIu6p8V6yDsn4/r93kiVItp6J3J@uQrq10/8OgIleniCuT6b6ZHKS7LEO9MCjQF4she2hfT6HsWsRoK2GsdpjNz9tH41Cf7RaxxK2HfGC/knEygJAkfbYnQfvN9JCUvEEW48lF1tlWjyhv9DfLMx2jgQWP5GSQO1i@d6jHfz0FgHQ/0CV0m/TncKt1l5XdEd@gjDsDLC1gVkR@pdfvkaZLYi78sc@OtJntRD64W7V0OLWBo/14rJNu1qZVnam/Xnso2O2tZvjI7Gph9MpwxsVYvWtTb8WJaUPZQDij9vR6PLkpT9tYu6NR/p4rT02fLS6xbf5GH4jPegRRXqkn@5tgvz3c5VDuYecHIzIvY2ywHPCuJM37DTW0IFd6DOAXnPzlZzxOzJj99JfW9nvq80B0Ec6NeHNiaVoeTANz2wC95DHWe26rRMsZIfuYyseX8gm7SKT3kFmnaf3BAjMU6ABRzZHjTtjoqQErWdSQc@HwlE/cTG3QF42bHKU1ffw6Z@hcyHj7CF7iu@o2VVJ9B7WvAFf1xv5dfa6y72qnqXp91fu3nqo2f3JjTTSb@WJSN0nGCWP6RC9PrjphH75th76x3Hmy6b5duwdw/O@rnAa3ZHE7xHBl3cY/U0h261C@JHe4fiUvFRc@@aQRA4h3D8obVzrn5wYx@3S6tvvWmBI1cluOtJsIXQSwFDezuW3ba6zjeq0T198Mh3jxr@xwsh77IlUgMl@Qm2rc5zOFcngvR27PjqKcGQ7BZ9kRwtTdyiTRMe2BTPYyRfkn7CZLSYjP6FPD1S173EMJttgIBicEzoAyG8dZ7U2qyzzclM8FGcbvfTAPuXDGXdPIOajHUXGFYhA49OWTSTiaEC6zQl2my37RjLImwtJOo5GUJTz9AE6K1rahz5@HY/QaxPow95MjsbHM8nIyZW2nicj8Y56cOU4BR1DsTmsqfWpC@PXDYEwZzDR3pxvSdrgZc8qg3WGp3265ZftqYt0IgXRJl43uuMF6T1ZU3N66sJi1gL/8oeDj8zU0JmepDCCMqPx3fHUAS0o1gt7jvHdzYEkOgrjq5dtbUL8sokTIogJtBSWFlSEucd@PTOeIuryUtaZdMRpkaXwAF/iNy4Lsz5Y/daJLZpqLMjvEiYLoeBUM1WSYhdEzq6jf5F@2ZynGiJPEdkzBpucU4JnA@PB5wus2KXlKxlgLQOJxdOJvVso7jEnUbiuB5cL2w8Jtf1J7x8pIyhw/BCJQNn7xZpOQXMRSX6hDKfp8aw1ZAU@vAJB2TplQiO@o1gEsU6MJbmH6uM9iwErhri4otzb8xSKOARjiqyqGgo5uoJi/lNggMX4D41mvlCvB@03Nlge6@jlbvkx4yOC5MA6@9XqthsveqvjcYFWo3zAyiJuq7z0BjnRv4RHWKzNJuwKc2SnxSs8j9CqQYAld2@qsYb3WuCEJeRxJ/vOQF6G7FM9NLCjkHebbJ6tbAEnmwO8xYoP3@QGx/N4EMS1MFGB4pwgy0C0xYsPG3ZgEDnilO9bl2/cY5mPa@Kt9MCb9MBOetBKt4jaQAX5ob4BOt4Gch182cC90K4NmP9NWWkaKl2qkNOlgqq@RffJ12CNIEzSpA3w2bopLalcJ5zuJAS2Un7a0/pWysedPGsBX6ffW@m2fIftll9TuQP7ebd8vFJ2AwnkDAb7kcVXUhpUJPmTtfy4TiEalsZjlazs2N5E7KxOaS@I2OokAGoC332O3fYsvcHiYx2NQ/qM6@z0sytoL0l98rwmw3rV0JuOtaePbHGJlOkjjFuQkQTKIckft1AQnChotNNzz5zMSzvzcgstQn10iqWck0J3OzhU7XUXT6Nb9y/443T2XeIcuIP9iR8syhdW5a0nLXYZRJTuR9d@Nu1qE1OfClakXamvjCKbspevMe5XEhUVZ6D8kLzi3ilTsJ4HEdWp0v@41hPbisLRFG/4vk6xOb0BYB3xfa8JMfGF@gNzRJ1zE7AKZWFBZ9Cm5shZ9tTOwzb4snoD@oAAFdRpY6ppsmSf60bPyeMcVj3ZcAwfRthg3DIaglQJHxC14P0Ysh@O@f@Lu9rmtHEg/Pn8K1Q6yeHWAZKm107TZmKMCZ4BTG2ThLlmMgScxBMCGV5CMnf977fPSrINoWlv7sN9AVuWdler95W0DyUqCR@Ul7hnmH2YLa6vJUS2AAYnda1XCZGclwx7/CTRu@EGbU9eeYnFAn5c0QGPaNmXE0KWnGw9Kc55ydAXi2RWr2T7Hs9pCkQZn7DPQ7ha/WQYXxfJ4NY5FnuVyofdyrvdnMq0qbpSerfPIOB6iqQ/7FV2K5X3u/uG4Uzun@TVxuLABK39HRC0RBMD/QnVzfgBGJmGTSMGR5zR1H8WTx/iYckwgnjINuDLBWsEVXkxi6UXZfbzihCaW8HfPcDhZ5ZEgKcahn@Mz9J37YAda1gG7hDdx9O7ZC5vGk0ekiEUqO9NXU1Go8mSDdG4siT1gUR38ZyU8sYUqyKxX1olC89d2F0saaOvoLz7l5MH9iOt1EDz1ATu9/kCkAEniqCQZyZxgHOSEL/BqJ/coTptEABeljINaAEoa8PFIH5RBoOF@JcyaIzy4WSwgGfevi6ZMvV@E24r1NzjaUK9b6ZgLhVOlpOdCjhqeKEI/Xp0ageuoOdO4J94Nbcmqj0RNVzh@J0egxqJht@k3iUUdrtGoe0o8KrdyKeAgh1SygJ/MOx2T7hnncANQ@EHwmt1mh5RI/KB3Y48N7SE13aaXRqsjy1BFETbj0TTa3kRRYt8i7nqZEaWTvh10XIDp0GvdtVrelGPOda9qA1mdeJmi44dRJ7TbdqB6HSDjh@6Ahkzal7oNG2v5dZKQEhq@8I9cduRCBt2s7mWUf@07QYQfiWXVZektKtNlzlxPmte4DoRMpQ9OaQ8ErBpibDjOh4e3DOXsmMHPUsRDd2vXYpEH0XNbtnHlDmj@BOtULk43cBtQWjSRNithpEXdSNXHPt@jXUdusGJ57jhgTCafsgK64auJQAzx6yJBmmLvtNztRt6rDevHdGY0e1Ent82qZBPSTEkpU1Ja6xgvy1zS0rygx6oQg9cAJY4bbgUHkCnrC0bWghJa06Uj0YMSYlRPpui7R43vWO37bj47IPMqRe6JhWYFyIC0QTfU5uYdjnXKCeSSz5SZTV0zbW4OIVXF3btxIPkKjbVgNBTtYXV5jSUzqktl42NW24vbuA93@VTppCXncQ7fs2lGZ8EVylk4V0adD6ubt6tfKOBJv1Ir2oXlMeqi2F8ubi@SMZXEyzN02RyB/tudm0BG8gEyN834wWAUbVRzglev764OLEvaJ0bXlyY1q@kXBHjZymUF9aXYpkqj6NJf8jL/BXbUl5Rh9vK17slHS/nbS3bqfHBFOXyMFbJcHkRhLWZSIESELEheka@1dgfixxL3mJetRUxYsa6sUhvb05m9DP@O3uRY0MugDpneW6hXMYalsUA8olI5ScmDAqikEH4HEByxSxLszi@vS5W8uyw5FcGKlOn4bhzWgZeF82fJL@Mr9eS76ynZ2Fx15QnK9odvHbTLsHT8aZUJlS5lKacs6I07fGfqaVhRjQpNCUrvsiqTp8Ut2Vy@BeVtkLzIHUlznAgLfvMO8VirrK3f7AW3kjDZdvCrXNg29B49yenO@e/xrmMQA0swfKLVJI8yS3VcjmXhmZlPJ9MI8NX/Q0iLZMhjakYqm9iHtbhIV@6C86np8F4mjzmpadu@DiwW9VuvU49J6Td//j@wx8HhvK4P52fWfK/Bz7A/2Pt0ix6mdA0jT/lWolD8576M7CcHLoPSg8Rga6nC40DAR6fes6UcwSJryHNQMjuDAgDY4BsFAASMC0I3M@PXxm6vm5smaoCFFeyaiI3d/1HnuH3aarEdWAgvWSOnrjUHvED2mnz1008zZCqQKqKxXf38yequbS44H6vUNcOB3htw9eKEaVU0PX4vq/PIEnFoM9kLwy4g89vqm7nSpHmtShotFcudk5JQrxal0KDtDDkErHoTGa6BcvAhELOVH2jx54CB8InQD3Y85DUWE9T7mjwHmlzVg1DUT4//EJFtL2dcvosYEg1lVDS/r8KHZNvDSyKPNAg1gjrk0epntMvbIQ@@t0Uf8maCq/eoHOgaqx6p5q7KTuKyoF2ia7eNYKMkLQyQBkOWqY8DB2lp6Ok6lxR03/SB9P/H3Wygf5nWnAS9Uxb3A8n40X8i5pkqlJXtHplpSRLfWIsd0wt02Y@qJeR@Z4vmJs0Y@oY3qPcWCIVqNJ50gE9CSlW3KAAVHLYNfLtFw58uRHf9GnldMRt9ze50z8dD@7uixqQSw8Vz@ieWzznsvQRObyYcgu/InLsmsBXOWI/j9xnYMFFvdjlk9iaFSSNt7vc5yDT5Tds9EhbOVdNqGFXt/CsOlVU09KN/1GdMMpGmaH@@p2moj8G@0q3Q4AptNLh6x0Q3YHw2ad8hpXaiOchBN2Yb3h6YSu/UKN4jG7zSo7LImL3HLP@Fa@ZMRQpXxpw2gGWoLM1VJhNl/F8ieFiJKmzD5GMmihusRsTMFG2yHQaoTtfs0Ra50F2mUrPZkrU11T67vh2DGDZWJq4dIzSCgJU3gVrSbT6DAY1@rV8FzLmb6HWw1X@3pj9qgzkfiVMc7xyJy5Y6W/NMo3QjHOJ2SWNQ5mW@oNbBBZ0HU2WO8kj/TGvHZVzjWlEawZGrNs06f/@wwUB6sraGVhR@DZOjUif5ED2ZUtPX/Ak22761MOTsjN/oUyRcBSiy@cGAmPWhCOaz9saS/cP)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Piet (116) [local](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)

### Explanation

Nhohnhehr is a 2D language based around rooms. A room is delimited by a a square box that looks like this

```
+----+
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
+----+
```

There is only allowed one room in the source code. We don't use this ability in this program but additional rooms can be created at runtime. `$` indicates the entry point for the instruction pointer. `@` ends the execution of the program. `\` and `/` are reflectors. `1` and `0` output 1 and 0 bits to stdout respectively.

The program looks like this and is located after the emoji-gramming

```
+-------+
|$0011 \|
|/1000 /|
|\ 0011\|
|/01 00/|
|\ 0011\|
|@ 0110/|
|       |
+-------+
```

This originally fit inside an 8x8 square but \0 looked like the start of a hex or octal (can't remember which) escape to CoffeeScript which it apparently explicitly rejects. The @ was also causing problems with Brain-Flak. If I wanted to I could probably golf it down a size by utilising the wrapping behaviour but I forgot about that until after I had already fixed the Incident.

#### Incident

Added `cl` to detokenising string near the Archway. Broke `1#` token by adding a space just before the Grass on the 3rd last line. I think there was one other token I had to detokenise but I can't remember what I did.

Comment: What was going on with the `@` in Brain-Flak?  If there was a problem it is certainly a bug, and I would like to fix it even if it doesn't do anything for the polyglot.

Comment: @WheatWizard see here [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1sXDLS5alQMDAwNY2q4avQNDQwM9IGMGLiIgSGaiAOQBonAtP//DwA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: Ok It seems that it attempts to parse debug flags despite not being in debug mode.  I'll open an issue tonight and try to resolve it when I get the chance.

Comment: [Here's the relevant issue](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/issues)

Answer (score 5):

## 129. [Brainloller](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainloller), 5009 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"   ^; */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉QQxQRrRrRrxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#cxx#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111x 
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^+.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO4O6O@MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPVs""o<
>-}

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="23 11 24 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezgggggggggggggggggc"
"fiyuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggxgxgc"
"fkTOOOOOOOOOOOxggggggrc"
"fmbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyt"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyt"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flyggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOxxxxx_oOxxx_Oxo_"
"OOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxxOOl__";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<9      >5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\                 _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///V222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002333 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5125 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgHdKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQBvErXW2t1NiUShKisrKysrK6sqUejy5uAPfzjAD13VlEVf0SzaEk2L7hnyVDSCdGZBf@ZlMxoKUxRCpY3@ZCyqlnlMHdAcTcuqIPfgnra0kajKS9GA@BBN64bWN/gxbQ14ixZNgddFk9Ymlj6xaE3any1M0/mxNpQDmHMsq30As0RDN0SLpEdouqkq/Ljb41@lRF8VqBuQbtI5Ufll/ItFC9p4zKs9EyBjNJ2rZPKl9CsMcZq@1gxTRDyCaJoaRiZoep4XhVegSQDlDVkrpcvnr5I4lj4H0nldEec03zUtgxcsWVNt3lUNrTcRsF7WQIScyAtJVkSTEoDmM1p3WiCIAfqANkS@Z4NRkmbQmIUejxRapgVdp7sKPwgKtCIDbIFN0CKyjl5CujIw6bk@BgymNha3STRpVRR7tKmLgizJAimdFueWqJpApRmkZWFEz2RFoXuiAhk2JAl@QEZPzK0om4Ag1dMoGj6C/qoC67tDEWBUccUEUQfuIRM0ZDZwZMWLmcHrOhAJjKwD4ZY8BpmRLbdJi7wpo1RCFlNUe4R/@lpeNZpXt2tJT2We5oHeiUFwm6KBjRAkeOmBaIiAkl9LjGdmyBawANmbpqsib9ANQxS9u7K7UyQUpmEJFlYkSJrv9NSdrxTc0Ix2jiCvW9SBEW7cXFI8HUzRh08n8E25XCdUvpyjvxw@YNgWVWhq3fDwXjr1G9pkHh5E@M65LtM3XijASgFXFJrRdIvhAzoQGLCAQIbHIIYC01BQV7YKpk9ftcWWcNlQPWgNuqjSLT@pmTAxDOyOG6byI6i0oql94CdU1pioyA@VjrHQBIIGvclPi1PgmqbabaTNCIcbAxkazcQm2eoAtlIhDAW1ArLncHRVrqkpEwIHOU0LBRC4AlkRY1GiW7TEywpmgXREZVNtiOZEsTDPRO1hy4PSEHtBekWGoPUQaKxNoTgekJII6EvjrR5IiAJgaAiNVBWTfvev/12v3wc8aUHQjJ4jri26pwlE/fGEWNApNAqspvIKIQvg/Fi6nR0KmPKK3OMtLF5dOEUQIkipM22i9GgNCjRmMnStAT@F7ihJomCJtpDbGtNPj/mRrTdkW3Kh4mO@Cw1LCiBlk2oH6M9ZaCVBpA6IzATGE0tK0AE9T7tN5ifPp2PPp48PIhDnDXqPDhmmfwICFzwiUXDn/prktNJbGg2Ui8Wbmtyj9IU10NQQHRBol5DSdFH1uHdwuP1uo@v2BlGfebwnckoISrLa87hBxjNQrtt7IqSEe/n48eRV7u0SAcsMsWBvFT2C10WBxiF9YsqMeVkN6gu6FXBCW2ma@YQcx@TgVjTy5XXc1I44IAMGiqWG8gFqKGgqoqh72CDnRS2BcHurjQn7KvoKh1PhY/nR5z5w@7arTjBATXcqin21IWuotRR9MAEdDUxRTR20t4GiK/AgPCYqcQtGbT/dJWJNND8oFqISZ6LbEOku6NGVGJEeafc4zB9APelg2PSgFdxuhxZ7W/0ZdAF0act8o5QVbQYFE9pw@AINomLhfB@aCDLbFUrbFbJLJDG7VRupoFcQW1ekE4GuDH0Bex2odkf0t@oI4OGQDQPY7L6ypYLG/AKwCPaQuOk3tCxBlxqDljAWtCCi6gEdJNrjChYyId3QBHsFLRc2EIpGd7vam55mGUw6cAe6esl8tUNh5dM7VgIMQJI4oxVe7U/4PppMKmThBUHULUdfQU1MCzTS62GHRAacMTRoDqjDz6/LJmOJM7pulYG63m49Z0TkUck4RlNAAZ1K847ZR/dkA7STsnhdOgBMXxXu@hlBdgj42fUOCStDAIRMnIvCxALlBoI8G8jCAGQXqVNt9WiPRa@Lh6jt0kHBB6R10UgMd/ZjiAoy6ygk410UAWzRt3hgjEVUZzsRpPG3I76OmTfHexBraxJhPNiKDTJ8EGTPYRpYT3W03GCwWZlKpGetzbk1P4HB0NWhm4KwDCxLN49Bt8vWYNINQrMyDWNRtCoqtixjGQvZ0uxwV9G6oEtN6EzMqgRGmHTl@asakbg1w4cmNQWjSTLpFIy2zxMQEY9bMkHLkfgsAm8luYi2JSjsXxcAEqAgcMojmUR/FkAD1Beq4HEFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLVhujyqDbZDBH6yxjgJqRQLU4iproaX7v8LRW2MQWc7uDQ01WPV/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75X6Fee59xGab41CylHUPf398HH708/eccw3h1Qt6CdQQQAfwAnjc3lQKg16v62wGFQ12Jbv2NZuzPSINNVHtU@Jc1wyLLldy@adqunGRcjET02AUucuoMBg@jaG7wcTDtSc/zCBW2SFY0zQrRRoM4wl0AYCcmRVlaRPooDBZkMeyVSRTFUVF0d402io1C@VuEFRl0aKcoWMj8Thr2bQN1IPAF7cnMJKhjdfqyKREYaDRrsOwCw3vnckjjtFOagRTJ87UcSs@jvFjnPYFBaovCHRAs2/XkQ5gAgFxKhiEmRfV9/kQkkwN15EOZJKgxOlh0OiuIr9w7AvGr@eGW0p/G@O@9PczEd7smcw6hcawxJ7WFZV5LBIQFSlozZdBVAuxCGVf6EDvPYg9ean5cl8GyoI@HphLrxJ4g7IpbMDAUoJ5BF2STTL3325Oat0RHiiX3VHDu0OGa5MS2th3@41S1zYWIrQgCCMN1eIm9AQWWHQHBcyp3@aUZHNAfnZA31D0NoXkNsddifzsATh2DB0QfZx1I0succ6GtpamwQx9RsDGmqrZpACrZJVnauQShPFxHz27w9AOMV1RmsA8junKKoa/ARZIJgik1O3K74ECX5D01XUPmDHp7mMbCNfgjaVC7zDemhiWIvac63/74x40wNvmGfALmH8Io3XgCfiGTRWQ3m0tJyvekJ/9LUtghhNF5gkbSOhbKAUe54i8sg7sR42qlw4EBrwBjbtYNS4IJ/7AMPoVObMpN0Rl0hNX1/2FEBbv2kN2blUekxrBFY07Ml6@k/2VNWfnxzm2oWh8j2Cx1z5kcdPadruIc74PlWO2NBJowu@gc2V00ZvFDjBYrIn9i@sb32pXWcfv1/qrA8lG@S4nwsyQ78rvcBGJiL0n13Z3QQMjICn8yA4@YXB/Ve3KGHK/D4aVc30PDExemJXovCAyM3J5V8WoE1O3mwJDX8FnKPbveyCrxdh14D1AqKZCfn6N2BFBEKBvIKm4vhjYYpH8iqkK312gETb49fKDBZJxFNRLSvD52DAOqesJ6WYlU9ffz482AMmfTO7PbS96EgSCJkmi@K0@C@OOPOaVQKi3FXxXBa@M1k1oD@iQn/Jgziq8CQJiOWwWp9As5OdrQotDiTBReGMT@orIbshZrTu8N3Xd5NFlQVNkRzJXN@/pwtfziA0aXNYmP5usePeWvz0w3XGYDqxD@zu0Jlg4fXxHjr5DPdkzN5wbbwlGUHuPd4I2w@@7vXegTUX7d/@QtdxL1Xeon4BCJAOmg2@z94RviSuuQ5Kf/Vwc7aXKEpS98cf0taYZMHU36VCQRQNHJYvnMGArij07bRQr78u0KSuaSdfJ79d4ASa/adq/@6V5m20yrwaEgd3H1uH92fYSRYY3Ok1@32lcXulrSizRZ3j4eVcCJoaEWt65fq@GW2sojvumhlqbO5rKOdd3VfsI/r8lHGRZ1MAFiK3gV6yoferMmbi@X0GYEeAS4P7KFdgEyRlk7Hnaew1gCIMZv1hd/xGjx3vcXY0e@oIYy2DNYYZkAgKWYRvQ/5jSIl8vrfd9OuoN2vi3KrHVuCNFBI1Nft80KR1iuV@Zg2PZ79dYkjIRJ@JeDVLpDkUQm6/pju8ninWqceisbDDAPNwxXUMtnangd1GN4znefVXh8IoMnfyb1sxeVaODha3j1LkKgSoG3mbsqxN9p3G3eFebqLWvc26gr3q21tshElN@rUZKfNtm2jHDTZF89yuQY/QFgAmvNgYbQv2O9neQkkUg@3cHMYnZYB7KuB5lfBXvMb1eqQT7FewRaFV5ZAZwUev7FE/ovZk6AU4mYS6mitYCf9/j9j5F2tU05de0DujTnoxmGhif6DrwrVY6puuLcRcsN2GzjPodLbCaJgK3cEr8bsNWAaX1nTjDb1f1vjJKba3x7S35XFPOTs@@0eg17LtcMBGMfxVwtdzFrALvdEGCLBkMf4/5o69sWrJiiqus9rrqxrXh4JV60RfAGLkXMIWBOBbJ7VcMer43nJiry7tAcw2/e5KDDFnzfCefLkN/VvF3Zw13JVGWpormV5lAarVaO93LzeKY74uFb0rOZgEB9xIFQ94J7l9KOLZFXYBs31AL9rROU0fiwlxd9xu/CwEacDL@KrZ9nVbAdcpv9tIgs3e9@Bs2nDrQBupAHBiMaQibu/d6DIigZbszfb3l1AFvjnDzNHCbrVa3Jm0Dc5u9iqYoX2evsyNB3E3WO5Km3/GTgTjZcLwizLXr0UFRFQyR7E@utsDoA9w1nYxhhmtpRpAmcB4P7/N5vZSdCSdJfRXAVlDE@QN3hG2/EpOGqatFYGWJvr@nD7/Mj9lj7oVO0a5jF/34aGMle5P5uU68Nmp21vtD/jF16A4E3IfuB/WYZt0EVFTAZt0Lyu/ASTK52HRuqk6r/JhsQmN4VdMTe6cbppLoTDLg1Z4i0k1QwmSCrRn2fq3tFNDANdX/@vc9x8emL0Ilx7IJNkpfRb8wbSwOtNknu1yn9LSu8@ijgzhmA1w0xNID2TRtzmQL1A5xrYGZbrPQSDg79Y7nGtxUsS9uUWE3Kup/9B@x7Eazqelpoi0WTsHrXKtKCZoyGav0TO5ZAzMI80JVEIknwHo7CEIIploGylnPTxfpnohrWj0kjCg9RdNGZJ8LKfmvf2/7J0CijCKE4VXxxD1pq0QaFTlxChAEbQJUr5AsRUNzQDzIZOiHEzQXQKhFO95LCwOeOE6AJAZWbgNYjO06kE3X6UCedqN7He5vnsiS5zBdO2/ds4@p39BjRvxvf8x4vzh8c/0QiHOmy0@vQE5eUK62k1lI3qS6adfh3OVUCx25iN/SWqgcr0wPhklzrdwAxsQHjMidOCNuAGTDTkU1g85Vqgn9A269BLXdaVKHnok9eAXqFh1FH0QYD3gI2V5jxJ0Gt7Qxy@Gc/oUeoKwEBJqLsnBnM0RBL4pxKrPakQhvbxoxObE7IUuo01AwFE6R6hw@pWBgx5Ah9jR0arr/6WEeYgMP83j@kTFXzHl4mP/Ahm6Be5oBuX5ksAPly7kvh8Ez9pdfTJgsulwv7hN7Ew16@eGXarGarzfSjWYduPliV/agoBljfqMpUBZ0BabxA00h3mLAFkMWzW9rj7UGWd8BuMdDH/L0KfqTer3rhDWow2pXwHVoB9cgMN5s5/5G9n35TXEr/S2Ao5kkmXa0KF0lguTIjNvc1qD@lWxhu2B3n4DOXnEE90X3qELCIxedAi4FgEvfySP6bS3tFvxEIqAZv82or@PYhwJ4tYF4C4BMWpeF9bXT7crtrfzLP0ONdRjX/qk1Jji@WmOE@FqNAXCTjeQopIulZi2/mwnEaeManJ@DEQOKWCJ9y3YytKVLcxzaVpoJBp6B7fbCKxvdatJT2ZS7ikjkTcKRQQHlgt2R7KSYqF1oVGRBOq2YoMl7PVBN3YWFmg1UepDsndsb6AGVdh0As4LrgdZPuyiENVNvHZtAc81goiX8bGc@JHAEs0ntccR8EJnf/et/ZztfPlgQ/lMnLEH4X9nhnxhk0FsHMpvGNWuQLa1ilTZhuLQrPubnW3XCEQtHRFmdiLQ8Bg5OCUMQ3CZ2U98NHs99C/gJjQDMRNWL2paUJxqPHvQoOmYYNDD6miIFyf6rOId2AGVNHIyeJ@gMCwMEE4vGIhwDRAamK4QB2UYY0G2EXu8xyBo1lfXUz12BPj09pV0mTLjFVOzEZiRzyP8Udv28JvQQYCnbFrmnIQ9k2eSAtDMnm@eQ93FezIpdzs256ccTMDPsdoGRykMCAOLFaNXhhwuGQs1hFTS6Ks4tos4XKxsLDByVOIqItkv0ClEAENm40WfztexuNvbQ3WFLmoPbzeBqI1gdwY5d@0Tn/if6wXpQHx3XXRoE5j/sESQVwn@2x593LT3pt56kntd@oFgb@nNd1XCrtwDU0p4QEwozXMy71VNcDiqgF/vFL4ASegL0LEGUh5puprP54mWlWn/jCUkg3a/B3LT77NT3EAj67x/XAfcrqV8xNVNg6teZwoqV21Rt1kwQYrNw8prMfaW9pvSd0tv2rurbsknCm4I49nsRk7lSoEDWFt9i36QyW4BZe9fnTake75eX@8fTswf14E3xv@xzEj8IHqFwQejBJC7ibnqPzimu9oob@ASPGVy5HYVcm0cg1k5V9v0m@n3/yPXzQBsvydWuNPpIhs6Ynjhl1ImiUMF39quh7kHGLoo4CNqEregFXbMilUNSNwUK1Js9v21qaKcubx9dcvzE1kyq2NNT4qzNqzAzMWTBhjaJgrYnscSzGKYxRWsz84HZFK5tkAnegkxmQFWs99B6Mpnh88bKgW2dUhfHcqCxogcVx8bnERQZ@vLB/HygyN0TPnU/p9deV19zhwyauiJbHvRDnAdxkgi18XixAtypIqIb42ny0fGZpFeujT7iHVmdAL@qmk5vJuY5cRWqwdyMzk0AOYiBSF9OxgAnkUtNxFFCpMtaADIDH90rIu6hFI9Th@C4F4XSgwNx3pP7MNJ4vH5QST9w3Mavkvf6YELtBj1ss@ocNwe3GfOrfEG3OMbf80FZ7YlzDzrpHz8idyDePWtP3V7XGxkgDqmOd2rvtWfqSlnwltNrN16drxRCMrlWBLt9J5kMDkwKveJgXgEl1i2jBEEYQz3SmNdpz4S49pp0kCa3ngeP6jctw0sHznA8m9Eq7fORGQlcSEKQJjklEpIVXA7z4NMrHiYF7YyxptrDy1LW6XsuGHyEMCnESx/imkIWzA2cjXspMDghyzFBCwMw/B0jRTOYeyFF9vWQFEvhgoABUHuTSUfuD0gHBF6QWtNnP9IbbbDpgTZXk8ljpzV21WGSBrE43aMxAO0eNbeyOIG/jmsTcA2VGEBlYaopg0L5fCWqKvRXD8jMGHonzU9AyAyvf/XopH/zVA4p4cAm8cLxlQJCd5/Wybu/KBrYM4fMCZnXnrzAuP/zAw78kjP0L5g/YoLMyRfPoZJaMGCMec88h4MU5wsf@XyH6pHnUEVz5McfcTr8cgjWzlPQFXTNAShwqHhPQJ7BOkodqieH/KnnsJcKHZEccOvzeb9Aht@YTPDLIf/CHP4I1oQfYgy7d3oOTS92BzYY5F6APuwhh4wfZOaLx0W7yIOPWPyh7PMhDcHDJyTgN8xD3UfGlYc6Q2beJ46Ry/THKzWya6usW@LNg5w2A53o47VGjxKfV3vV/GkFvP2wzp60ffbRH/5wwMVgEvUpFvZon0Lhj0cH9MFnF3PkMlxfHnLTE/c9L4WCz4/VUbV6633wuA@yFRcXcUFtfjqhjxjqgDlif4kzzM8//wzWJ31/FjwLPnrvA@7He8/8LB4/OvHHEkf@z37O7T85oBWO5TivJxTyMvRDnX6I8/yRLxL6rJ7IsqybvR58tQE@OgaWWAql5AN8PFzV7Y6G3fWf0Bv906eP8Ef@4bO@xd@PJMaJJiBvPx@9tOd5Th2cfbi5md/UDPybf/3zBN9KhgRbDMeFHnDGFo59/PwBqiz6yOf4@DOZx9CueMKlaZ8RmB4ccFyU1g5g5JuLdJeezwP4oQ6E@fxgCYncwYL8PWGY4@Y0dfCbVMr3nZ/5OhQMPq1C1MHPpz@n/gkf6gDmGQdnZ48vL77AffAnRP7oC/hO709Pg2dn87PA49k9dfCFOpi/UAchF4jLwxF1kJqf1ggF97kzh5ZnZ2JcgvBp4PG@WgLjt@EPnQYOQoV01h@qNzMHHNxFN7eYGMbbWj6dqzQBulrKp@v582Ir36xCvPn4dPb5sy8IfPwcPHsESuY/@M58Kcuy6LunoyD91c/TnpB9Sx3kzuZNJnAKxJacmBopJvAAdw9eKOwX6uD@4N7zKfQpxCrslOVG3Ohaq6z/I5VY5fN1pQKJ8pwdagY7YAdcD1uWFZvsgl3M2bFW4XoQFOGPHUNQZqU522dVVuW4bWRf@R9XtOuKBqg0yGbNWQuxshJc@5XKNSCToOAh/Mksy86Byjk7hX9WIVLG/fTEkjp72YcH6p52/SxC9w1y7iDrDsbcbvkxGtOfv7yEYs/3ZHCPJh/vxblsPbpov/vp4T6ZTLofTw4Y8@GBsTWaKxRxnSDIy8vTUy7dSD89MbjWMT899H32BT7DJ3XmO3Uunw56Z8jZ4OnHB8rtmbXbbfy2Z9OZHSIBO669Tty@IQH4TN/JuxuY75cFj@c@@vjlxev1fnhwn7jtmng8tAgmq8fFPcxDEh1yeYktm4SBgAujuRGLes/OYlG4jyW8AQ9Lku0sDy5d1x9cQTI3DhInh1QqbRj8ggBFYCx6cPHG04PrPvSYSiWjJDoaSMZozQgkw16X1/sTd3rqlBHyQrTLPXdphpv@8rL95/nycuohHy/@eb0Y6fyeeT2Q7I3C3fyLZ37qOfVgHERhri8vZxgkcF8gdO/xPnpfXuw4@PV4T22cZ17gHS4A/DP@ayZt6rT74OUAbQiVjkS9nu5C9EZinoQv6fylPkIFPK6wOwz1crl59/3956PwUTxy/@nx6PHIc3oUPHo4e9zR0F73AQ2yvJK9FHeAfKMOgic1FxdyuVEWT3AlX1PEoAIT/HDyZFcY3E@eo9efBJf0Hfk@3x8lk3bZR0e/fIRuA@igMBd8DkB@aQ99ena6FqoNSu8ZfL/QDpMh/PIF5MxOA5PE46zVPzzMWdIfvfRJN3X45YB/OSH46ReX@2RHXgl@j/uEbOa4vrgOeeOee3S9uA6/dF/QdjvivMREiEZOTo4idjieOIGhmjtyUlhI8dprlVFIEU1eID335ADFyQ0890KtUl2xL8Mwp@8wyReNRpkQ/M5/iOVDc@oENz3sHRZXwGV3IDqRJPgOaNNMUjA96ELLz@g4C4OgovAGrUnSRzse5jl0VxTB1BQVBVfrcBoA1rDSm8HU8yN1AIoGjGBThM@4yosTUZxNJjNx/cnK5jE/pD1DmMbi5/e//at/Ad@/h@@f29c//z@SUfz9/W//5//td3/ztxD5X@D7f8P3P//@t//2j@0vuf8H@P4/W3H/4Hy34OwvBbj@h9//9i/@7ve//Vd/Dd//1fn@9evv7/7yP9n//6/zh8G//d1f/gP@2DeA66/@7Hf/9k@AxL/E8L@EMPw70X8KQdoXsD@@rXT6l0MWDCn64ZdN5J/SvzAcqHuaWUcC1n//ywN6g3E25ArnLwzLQbQN@We//@2/@TuI3YH8k1X2zzTEvYZ0xGFV0J8C5N/s0OlA/ikVp5tV@KkVzy8aW9dGPp29oGJ0plLOvbpEHaAoXcoXGuvbuJ26yhpdo@jkS6XXt86lo01ogUfxEmmetpUwD9NYPBojiJ2Wos6@BE6ps3q@AcmNCp1IQLx9P8f7cAjvqbNqEyOKZXpB0m/xWq22TJdLg9vAC0VhT/hIR@N@fzAYhB@8@smHXIOHP61AuPdNlAPqGldbk5y9@S1jDggZYhK3@6ADzVSy29rFh7Un@vuRcMEoDBpyfwBzvJm2BjBNE4bO9VD6ZmBtUxfQYcf4xCM@Gm@hmQ/Tf5YKYvcOhZKJaCIZDiX8iWQiEuVi0aifC/m5eCKeZP1g4Ce4WCKa5PyJSDIciUSSfpoLRZNxmA6qPVliGDAWOZeLJgFZFfARn1N8VkoLDs6og54owRz7Az339LwfDnqrCHqSoF3hxANLuxjGReFmyNE85QqFaegHoQjN0S7KtaQF@oDNJsIsmKVdvMkk4ulY2OV6IinwybIuVw9v4myikIm7XCLeRBMsG8@4XBLeFApZtlBwuSr2DX5crsXqhmWhoAHe5WMsOlq6ZLzJpm24Id6EEliUyzWyU@yb8eomDmAq3oTDNoLnNTbEbdglJUgmy75h2UzW5ZrYlUjAn8vVIOjC8JeATArcdRVeGLlcfQj2DVCrLpijCqTVQUwhhE5FqsW7XALcCAtehXzSwBKX/dcfAVPkxaS/P2XYeJUyhz@SMmpUNp@5nWiQlHF38fZjYYr6bsrzVkplUelVGvjBFJjJ9lcp/XWBJGXvB1MkjRBFJnQaXp8qc@0JUlbk4se@VirK05PrBAUNRZ5eeLxfiCXsoU15KUKX9LD@CZh/0U@ThCsWdx0fwdX1yRWG4NxDs24Y0F3uB5fLe598/OSKR13HMHUNuH/kPsEEMek6dsXjLtp74gpBf4m6XDE6BKJ4B2Og2A@46U@uE0O0JoZKh05ekIJlij0hlNDPHrzyfvzter84YN2TF1wbAzKfPUufzw9f7yekGOxYMM29xwuwHLwnL9DnGKf3QYDiTkOg3DBnyl5TA2iQpjWA3e3X/ZYGkz0YpOELc1hM11M2OzyupIcmY3XyweWYMvZKh8ftjofcbq/7BJB8pF1bys57QkimbdZ6VvxxAUeAP0mwvB0meJIBsAvpQBIqYJP0323RZIyOTYs3cO2LFHlMu2JJF0YDyGnSLuss2j069nMB/2fKNlJiHHXwQvXwmZ1Ikj5JnuCEFqzn0zOHuit6Ee/7LrboPaEO3UixO7wznzggv4c4Gh4EwlpEOzg8PIQ5dOPMFXZVgk@njDMbPmPINPjh7MSXimR9ZGoZXE22z3Dp4M0nEqEMEZ0seniGkj0/SUSRL33aPAB0J75/zCcI5aYAKXWCJqzrQEfJF5QFLl3QDzatp785IBMYuvpltek9Ucm6/PE1Nht/XCdPRt4/0t7flGXlSyIcOCOrWChnNDTUSz35U/ynxE/XzUqzUvjMHieOEw8Pb2fkn2F0kGt56sD8xatFud@olycHx7o7HHGHYdqdOrCrzcW9B2eheNDkFwePjq@YJxJHUYN7Ys6GOPpAau9@Zjs30zFZmoCiEn/U6/fl0B9d//zLIcO43TTNHcZ@Ezi1/0/hJ1uxy3DFoi4vOtGZPz399HRAg1VKu0JRlGQfQ9t257aV7JkfqeRPPDLJnyhuIky4Xd1huug9YhimFYJBNZmMJWIH1B8Y5mu7T5C6Xo6VRNEwJ@N967FpQ77mca1aXa/JQuB6shQNuK5ONFqNvjQOv7jhgOPvdpwzJG9FkYPAduMWJoM@LxgLZhAeGUVOkqMl1A0enHRZxHeBPsJj2NC1z0t9oT4ArolgEXcZ@DmhqA/ot4G3nhWcn/7RtLy4p816qQ8fHF1nWkHTekLkmMmJDHAnFFhhwB6@1zNpXConW9S2PyCPXhCabruGKwvazmQSZW6bEsSVD8vdIviIlmwqoDZHNCmRUI6Vs4v/YIN1JxKSUiiW8pCHTtES2XJxcruMLp7hQar3UfI6hdMsRCEWBCecIuAICOgg0kNwe8fodCh4CKSP5jBdIls3AAWGlZ9Q4qclJ@M93j5CdkQvCYpmAmK7dI9dA/roySnWqcNqCMFKAAuxdkQxk3HG6At@p/XwYen7Ry/9ZeXa5MFU@pQObXyvHFzQGPZZeSSjMO7ZgkMOR3HYTLBxj35o2hPbRcazhnNiNox6oY4s//jEbir9hLryCN4vuLR/8pvxjz8KP@n348cT7zhl4dXnG8M4MfLINsiRlRqnQDz0e/nxxLr3@eTH1Nh75cF7GIJgYH2hJJvZptepG9RcTQEtuP1nev3LezXwG/XRX7hXfUDyxH90l1r6@RTrn8NXTnF@xf@c4px6QJlWaulTT/hT@OIuw477EYyZPv5kJwqzjDxKannPP6aAHwpk9PkKUBmg07xXfL5HLxSuQOLbjCfKjz/yPuVsfqIEAl6E@in8qXBvQeDRl8L7Yw9/Ov@0vJ9A/mMPXFNQjOIF4iGfw@uXNe1A3wnw2G7TDek2jXMkbw7kjVOpo7tPR3dHqY8fl/fzwPjRb7P/mN1IAxI/R@JPtty7PEd3XvoVS8hCiMf1g3z8Q/DIpF1@GWyYozu/vpXTpvDoDlJ0GPgcql9QX5IjvFY7WChhjkuSfYgKOYaBzP3ISWMmOV3R6qFzJuRNm4IsO@C2V60uw6yJRxd@P61qaoAnEJjmHCmIiQ/zT5@oVdGOvwyUjMqli5NNmH2RE6UMXJUhx1PaTvnf0q/71PBK566nQvXiXZ6GaVc4ttVdiWoiHc40hHsEQTXwhX05sTWW7SUFyoZoD4Ah2gPhAqhFkEmOnnAgU04itNaqgSAX6gnJdm3HUzxM1E@g3jY9H1SITQZ05j1kyP5hiugmkCcZQrR8SsqDAHQV6gNUAmnAOsiP9BkoMvrHH2nn9jQFU8k4jgUIhnBDH4dAbyiFwr@DUsCBVA5BRlEfkkKAtg@Ygr59OwVF/mkFOa65HsjgG/ptD90g8dD1TFTTdkxHvnltMrAtPnwYgqnoEAT/xE6G/JD28ocDZ7g/prOV62qzka9dp@vwC/Z@YnNq4fH6fLs3B2XpeABWV1aJJ5vA1zixcymA/QJWH4iU1sPTK3v0ZbMEU/5yzo/PRgLrD@zVFBhQj9eYRJOcOGMGNaPPzOSRzOyeb4snDRKnOXKabmB17CCSQwZnZeMuv/GWN3HlAwZz54GunYNPx6JpOud/BVbnn5IzXsmDA2P0f4de6JwXRvwRVluqZAMfFyT9xC3EkPsyOdRyYCPYyU@OdrLs7KR/UHjOV4@3eJRoKgkz9GOa9WOAWwVCq0B4FYisAtFVILYKxFeBxCqQdALcCjNnY4ZpWTgc2wTjm2BiE0yugxF2E9xgiIQ2wfAmGNkEo5vgprTIurRYguClD1bcJF1XNDCNiyRWafi4i2qRyCig4V5HRoDQ0BtIyB55EwnlJXYj40nWKajIVBAoFIpt7kH7rGBTHpsqv02H3y7ZvnMiYayi7FkOEdi8YYBWys/xFEIQOu8xje6/FAVqlxYUkQdjQLTASkkVQP5F77H9WIyxON64ACOGFLe@h@x48Bfk4ciBmrb47EkO7Uu2sYX2YrOfK6LXjNnyn3aItKk83hlpbYyRnbhtrB9RwSJH34EI2RDYBrsO16syG8Zkb5Hhrxe5g3BvkW@IsvFG9@VC3ngI8tQqKxn/CbbUqjzbThFJa4MZ4JyeTGTgVYPi81GpL9yx6/e//ev/nf79b//ib@nf/c3f/n//@X/C8H/Cn/8TbBY6tAb487/An3@PP/8L/vwN/vzlViYCHz52/e6v/wPc/o//kf7dv/gLO@nf/J3LH1kjghSM2uT8q3@JP3@CP/@Xyx9dA/7Vn9mAmMXlf6F2TCsPQP35f6FpKA2xrJH99d/TtMsHBobHkbx7u48/bj1NYSNYs@GehB5fp9u/wsBAtrNenwvwOnfc5s6HDeDdQm7weBzwpu@BOWN78aGWFnhhgB7zTpRmov0joAmjmcE@yNusB0aPszzghtr/9/Qx7fYhDESTx8JStg536u/U27VJRVifiwHq8NA@BxWGvWtKYHpLgXyTmcDCDOK0hcxIOVtGHP6W8bjx1QDiWkmWbHk4L@WUtcoNkx7aObUV/jdTXRRaHIbsx6rI6cmU4/zNbRW4o25eNRuU8joGpoybBy22s5IIcaxDk0C2Nb@RsXhDuOB/jW7Tck63yVcKrzoMfrpgYo62NdK6oBTtcn0DFjntwHvR4grvwtv0OgD37HH4ceexjX3ArtvbWxe1FceiDBk9D8GwVSlbZayTuN2k0FZSaCsJaLZxEl0TDYVe0UAGDtSLu48o2dm2VNRuto1wYc9ZtQOSAXNBe0HQLykTc5B6i5po5F1l9xb5FkruMeX0kweV6Jwz2uV9kwFw7uZJvW7L/ajZNzBvG2p/TuT2TsxOa72PaSfPVqcg3KNec2ndclxyX8vtFvgV1Nyj7zsLCrH/xIIC31lQLPrtgl43K@bdQf8@f7@tdlZqYq3hN8jsjn@wM0Dh0PjXIHobdYQUGyTo8cKUJ@1MebozjfbsOfEX4pnV4Qg7x/waW0cm4CSmrFmivTzwWddgyqGhFbx1pv@@F3A4R@j3Vc0Qze3HsWTbtV114wOBgtZXYVTz4yENsnPgNO7F2o9@744r65HNsUKz9msCELXNKLQ8n55kVbaensD4VCTvhoF4GxTQ39hN4fsFILSV37M2bSu6R8PDZSzvt3ESe9fO1pCFkaeiO4luKCRNw4ROEBWYfNEDXhjhmzIIS7CK5OEotEi7lseLTBxoY60vqho@C4m5X6EvbnAjQbyuE1r8NO@nhS2KnEm0R/DzXifr1a/OSl@FPLx3nT@0i2CHGX7aeM1j5Kyxp7ind4uzs63Kq/96euvb9Na/Tq8kG6b1mmYSias9eP11RYc9GwwAuCEj/G0y/M7jz2/I2SFlHY0nadsZvpvEnmgKMPwhpWkATTvgQQnkw7@@M@FuTXjrPf5/vQFX2fPf23zEmK0vQN@M82j7kSmaSQ5/UAXRA@BFL@qet8WtRTv3nWU5Ex0yw/PTLqK4VHRbh46p66JqrjdaV4i/IfPoJPJG7onnSMpO3EOTMfXTo9D7TZR76okKvxB7HgfSv4V3VeOayPeIvvq@iqOiI0pPs49P97B@bscUI48XEaDjd0SG90@93vfFygaR19JDNuMIhcX3@UcW7l6rZlwETdl7IJoBGvSAnCtATnPQF/rCfiRRsV@x4uhRe/yxW7KMT2p@kyHAB/sFGpx/U6z3a@qz5llX6TtGhDVscLfK@NTRCiM@9/O2DX8di75dU7LKsM6UWrXyjnXyXovLX2vxLalYyaRtlXyfSH5L6L5b5rZEzUa2UWHZXzeEvMGc5RVFEDzbGO2Yr7aYpr7RCRiHLaap74wqT3sU6jon0XQWHo6bsu0LLyVDsAjXKVxbcEWEMAd9sgVqVTe0a1dLXiRlzOtbVosTcy@gLbrFRe/2PuIWFLUK40Luy7pM4d0yhTdlCjtlrnvAbpFbQJSwU6TTCtg8X2sCRZSsd7QzJuHMHS5fU9vwUTXewL3XL27ZfSz7affUfQwK2S26j/MeUMrunvs4RwKm@7hOAiP38RUENn3L/Yv7eNUtEMCAWxL4jPGOCsd7wX2c9XhfKPJirVW5Qffxuk0B5pN9SzjyYi@vdp1df229qiqKftuo9NMoMSZcNKzW/aOffFn4J6DOYT2Q@DFFh44IME5AdgaNrRHDLgeGjSB5c49n3/BxvFqactY3NmsokO5LbS2qoJRMiD5yH7h3lZFNGKaSxUe4AoGoN4/3U0Rzb2Zm3yLHKR0klDTybvmEe0FiD/Q8JP0egLcXcZRN/lV77aKwG/D76MTM79H5hpxVcYQidAbw7iELmfqz@yuVwrZ@dfCL3frbLfR2jQAbMbACsVuJoN3S6WDDoW1KCtM1fVdISCru9snbefDjdEqU3lfZiFZweuY7ySTaqRkqhu3O7/1adbbyIWk7KggT79lHu5etxwWiizFpo@u2LFW78wEJWzqnR57ZFlFsc06QwNnqxk/GiveGoVVeu0iiuXbVJGQO4iM0E96yS9/sy@CDNb9u@rrKCSY40IgItnKuS7H1q/Yr7HfNtt9XBvWKCa8K2GdY7x9K35rXXx1lX1GubIp924CY6Kdz3r3G0bqEDcthdrBlmX9N1t6Y@Pi2BNvItwtdY39l7a/Ytp4TfINvr@cWNi60EozpbuQIF2ZHofcZ9dYiUabBldESxJIcPHbF15RuqvZ1Wu2K72tiTMExGi6/uoGN3QbebjzERypgvGK53cvx7VJkn2Ldt3FNfWvnwt510NBLbH2M0VYkqHviv7Z20YKIylMtVymXOjDoxuNx79utCOy1kHczjlNf3SZYT1tCfjyzgrygEn0nBpphfXxQXW9dykgEGAM82bexxc/p415Hl23p81d9F/LZsFscdXCNNt2A39FKaOrwOGTLDl8tYIhoeY54B8nKvAV@@8lsDXeNUDpwQ@fpiQxfT0/onPP05Ixi2DTrbaQ/HDhvhAltvWXyYNeb6Z03/OICwGRsv@PQWYBzHvm2/VAO8H2i6/cDr3NNVEteOTvg@hBuUa09Izxhzmu/hnQVY78tFCTVE4rgFDYUxScS7VwIjQufxLXSKeejbejgeYamrqnO60RH9itnyemK5mrplZA9UWc8cQOxSyEPUm5RZDtkrfbFyBsCydmq9usYedVeQl7xxk@L/SDZ8QklYcoxknX7SKO164fpJZkIwcRHC3jcVcQxvqUPZHfPavK1DK0yKMj9PggS45xSazu4NPDFfQFNCmQ371xukXctOkfBOT5h5BhGZx0Y2OnZOWvBpEMxsKaSfuDs5guMRTcZGs9TYImTFoGCbxwucTuY8G/l/ehZeHev3OrjRXwfPU/YsvZjWzK0jgIir27x2Xmaa2tp2tm0JHpga@dydWwI5RzzkiL7lEH0UdM9rgPX6jAVDNpuE7wirE4h8OD5F8fUB5UoHvQAowXbtwYMXBWNNrK95l27pKr0D3Q4RN6dBeURK5UUCzjsnb0d7JAGWZFY27vPUTCuH3quH3AzkfpwgLrQljXMvxJlDJND4TayTH900NkbKtiV7S6wuolu3YRhqvFhT8EfPS4fYPG5vK4dTADv7H58sDXv26ygFL1/YBq9WLugpdPpxpgzaufpfnqQrnXgPsOWfO1hJM8w@Qull84Vu4tzLd6YSiG20bnJdMO@arw31@WLcfZCz1NypDP23YXnyYvIMpoNZ9MCeyudl6RIPHsr3ZpiWhGTzHQ4uumJNb3LGaZ8Vb4u15ZMoXnT6t8Mpbt2exhX65Reu8v0b@biTaKtTlvNZNG8EVvZsjUqD60Jt6jE27HmTDUzrUZmcLkozkbzYkzryNHsjRhvSfrFTFhEdeGiSd1NG4NY/WIxSnLj3iKdNXuduM/HdLKZfuJC6N1Jl/XsVa9vRLvRUT3Jh6fjS0lfDK4u1OfSMFufCj59WCjGppRaLU5nYqQ96ioX6l2t1ermMtXZiDPv9N4w0r6eWN2EEQuHJ2lxMIxEixPLSJQy6au4lUsXWwXltmXdLVqJKmVdWI1481JIKr5pxRLCk1yTMdnW/FK@qs9iF6GGdqFeKsVhdXQ@Oa8q@mSUi8iVxjhi9G8LXS0UuripTy86JcqIXLY7idowlMgJc4G5imraONxIlkvG9XySea6I7axQz4jdGJuJ3ua54XVlIVSmpVqtXdXbzXHcvOKUuwI7pCq3Qj2dGRVK4wTXKC@KifNifZLNFufTbkjqa@lJrx2@vo3NSmWx2L5hwhf8xLr2ydmKwgwvL81Fq3lVvC2bd9Ctry/liLSYZ1oZQ3rOZc3rWokpG6NBPTJUe3orLmc14bJajFjFUfpi1r5LFjMjUap2R9qo0VbaE0vODZkCtciObppdcVaQlzM@Hym1bphhviZY8XQ/XGeGktQdKRVz2T8vLfv1SbffS1bO2Zz4fNXLtKK1vM5dF8xIWV1QnUZGkpe1G4kbVZMXxbtuPi1fq9FsVdSr5xfTeSjUkaXqLLrk5rfDQkSeCxG2VMncXvtuLkM1X8mXyVS1cKVPhXKF83Y/euXTCuKSKUn8czzrMyaTyDw3wVc9lpqqYoyjCpsoNHyDuGm0k9fXs65ZvK1l24KyTNxdj0axuxp1Oy2amhFKXBbSSaY6Yo1zflgu3sVltRCZZc6VfLLYXjYTVr40URIXpX7usmbkGmPhNpnv1xeLUT9xKVZLozQlJnK12rDbb3XnnbpZXbDXEWHY9eXP8@XnPvTjVr0QumxmYv1JLdy6yqnTaqPgW2q37ZKeLY@4fDUxiTXi4TE1nV8m0nVLlfXc@XUydjORS/l0rt/Mcpoo3j4LV9yIrzcWbMKMGzeF2xvd9FmNrhbpDjLhxc11h2ndmWb0Qqbu5u1YMT0yhKve3Lo04w01pFVuWO5GKjeV6LQtP3eq2jA9Zq6at0umO1sW5lVLsOojLdqLR0fnc/PZWF4ZV1SiM@SVZjmrlYZC7KojL@NMlFMbnax0LXQuQ2y62b@4FgsX0/6yKY5Dw4vnyYXAC2Y13emeK7HpXPdJ4cS0RDXK7dt@/PmZ7YrlTlJOj5q1atEKNXhm0qmXos@ljmkWhGZRzkRkdZLLdM5H4@zdgm@Y8@WkEesq0qJqhNg8NS93rlvCUOubBfNOGC5vC3fq9SQUu60MpbjVG3FjmSu1JDZe1mu@nK@qnHf7i1hrIk4FsAz1m6LOZdLDYYWqcOP4NLNImpZ6bl6Vu9nLtJxOlxKhGz0Uvxhlzy/mPbnVbJUverwWuetmw7FKt8@Geplyvl@NjPvxajkeKWWpRndxU@N6uYTMDXglO7xcRPRkKZSJMa1Z7eJm2BioZSWbbs@lTFhoaLN4m5fUpriMxZlr1jccJC/VNBupxqimlbOapcIs7FOviteh6mIh3Hb5SZiXnjumT@gsB8tKS@Q1ZVB6rnGN1qSUlYfDViwjNNhKps5OluaM10tVKpmrqlyuNJ8WZoN6mzX13IWe6M7LvWy1Knb1XliXupX0XGKn7fbdzU2zoo5vb8YXtXi3suzxw2jLkmqxytyinsHkaU1LzUJ3npNMaVibPqvn88lti4k0z8elZm/qGybvOtOwfFthS@VMS@InxZt@3GqW5/r1pSIpzDhU6TPUrFldLi0xreXLs@vOXGotl2k5Yz5z8yuGL50Xc7eWL5kvpHOVRp03lErlvJRL8@PZ9ax0G/eJy/p1LyqPnu@oqqoqIeOursQzbNgMNaO5ZVYYnrOT88y4cdlIcjrXvGhdX19xA0UYC/FOJRdrXwvtdPryanEp8a1qVa9eNRtUxafe3t01mEpDKSWlUrHW0KLFqXHdbsf5mZa@4dliZNydleaZ2fVk0h4nL30dS@TD2lIUudpMKTHiBchOghIn02q2XDUXoefl8Lk/zWm3rWRaP4@lswupNxWnSzadm/oYszCf9WKyngg1OvNzqSNc9/tXtcwgrE/1RiwbpS6T0rXa6mYH18mFeHVRahUmlljvdSOyz2T1YeMm3TSbwkI@F2KDadPsKND5JD3ayGSTpnKXS1wZso9NCBlKaF/zVaY0iN6WL3vaLDu/bi1yMOVIcFKVjWoLtTVJjNSLKzNz1X6@SiT6ze7FCAqeDO4Ggtz0ZXpd8UZSytTd7VVrlK9OWszw5vY6Xm1e@BLLsHH@LGiDcz65aCwrLCtKyf60OJmH9ZKQOE9cVQTlcl6uNSWxH6uHbpRzdUnl1PiATUvcbDpTGd8imknk@1KmWVaNXFO4iItalWeYefvOqrRvE1ehc/aGrY9nbMi8njGs1FHlRafc6YR6VGZqXuntOjfN@y6sdKc@rAnnClNu14pLbVHKh8xmupyVriazhV5ayEb4TiidZ5WqIHNglkRj/YbRHC0z0y7VlualbCYRvwtdgASZppKcdSK8KJh6fz5kSteTC2U@nIxahm88Z2q@u848mhy0BiYjlEqNcnGWN6LapTlUqVhMCF20DT1u1p7Hi2LWyg1aTSWSTbb63cpFh7luSFfJm2z9Li5Gq0zxWUy26zFWKEXbAsPVtPHUghFJ6I@o0oLtGYIiGnx8UnmO5icTX28xnVg@/S5@fpVo90dZbirwvnC6qz3z89alwsrluNg3K@3Z9LbQBgtRbU2bKlW4a@rhK/lCql@0KtcjrpquLS0mk2wLt5F@x@AkVZrWwlb0sij244KUy9@NhrmL4nOR7UjP7IxTjJubcOGCo@KSL2NpPYVp3eg36jLEi@lOJXE96y2z40FZEi@KoZzRqcV69SteycMwKj@XWL1VOC/d9brKgJE0tVKvsSx1Fwvl27e1Z27au6kuG9r8wuhfpqtK@FYqqlr1tsXlbgymHM8UbrLD2l12kYhVDaUrNvqJhjr2nYc1gU@rpRgVF6diptVmmqIc5uLzZZcfiQx31x6NEhfMMmYumbRqzoaJ/jLZPR9z7buydt5YjJjz8fyumrnlJqKP46qCTt1Yy2r0/Lztu1qcN4t9pVmUBIYfL4bmRWYiXs66N7G0L6GzDV@@1xrMS9W@3s4z8W43wdXD4XbEeu5VF@ZNmWrlShfheG5hzaX8aFKeJy70dKy@mDdvIpHR3XBeSdRjteicm2qjfEYv9KOMdmvG1Xnjol/IiHnpWjKvl11hTMWWk3KxkMj7oiLfqXbuWCnPPNd7ijXoS42r23A9xgjRi0p1dneXSzPjuDTMF5VzGBNn/PV8UR92Rt2bihmWKa3S8RVjy9iyfndT7qnV9uX1oDvrx@NV46I1TE6WHb0m13z6slnsaue56ljJLW9B4GK1ZHTYVPLNtnybq7EVyoq10zOwwblMSV70mWKUvZJU9nI@Pk/ejtuxUWfUyk5rnfloGKvHo9pEXMat9nN0IjbjnctxnRG6ndnAFzqntPpycZu/iRil8kwvWVVNvGITodLdqDnOT5q@cfaq0LWybVbvhtql2cSXjYJVkLhuJUPl7tUwUxyd35gXN6Ek1SjIi0lieB4791VhMJkMzUqipYSUKdNmlNZsKo7GLF/O8S1j3m0WSr1yL5RgdJ8cn1lXsefLTvWOt/SIylDmItab8b6LPFgQObkTrftals6OYS7C3k7DV2o/HDLV23pdsLJafNQMJ8VIwWipWmuuDVsh@eY8PpoJ8tWQyojLXkRp1tq98nw56yVHkR5fnzbThVu1Hc6q@mBuGlwseRVq8c/VsRGuWHq11BQy6s2Y56WZb65kctdGfUr1@uV0r114nkjTVqSSjqQXtz02MrmbDjl1eZvvhIbVbnogzWrtyLI2C2d655xaG8v62AgxbKOl5keJefNCvKIul3lxMUjcZKqtSPNqmByFlf6oXmUXo4osCXd35oQrdvqlG65XjLYyN8nRhWSmxXgzKV0OmXm5W7mLZXtihKV8g@KYCWVLQvgyf@uzLgUl@iwvubK1TErqotyUu/X@NK2XesPmpJy5YDJcaHo@r4zDFzUmPOEz40TuyugYCiXmo@l5s3IdMwd3aasV0aqhaUK/q8r921CvOuCFMRtLgA6@7nXvFs10LTMrdcoXdTOt9peiz5hdqefFQiGjUhdSu/xsPvOaNElHmpVS5@b5Jm30G9GuZRa5@bPILBZq5TIrCItOumiOyq3LulqMs@Ne5jp@M@iV1KZWlcNXlJCMj27jjFoXLiesGKmmI4Xn1rnwXJzGatpItYRG/o6zyjVQdsVos6J3ZuNldsBK83Akf2tW@j39DnrrcEmFJhe1Tq8mDdX5rHZpta7C4zo3as2UUUzldV8kn6xUeK4fxklY9FZTx5py1bdu6@XplcEwg2VsIurn4pVMlUJ6P12sxS5D/Pl5J5dscuPnkhhKXEcm6VmoUrv2qVFRzxX7Y4XNjmpD8UaGKUM7Vh1esvWy3OzfTbK3yUWdWna6UlK9bM@0q@xolhtNh43mPAzTq0arZJr12q3VK05D3cu40q0Meo1cIXsjZHnejFfUbL4y0iet7nh2EYlSw0L4dngdv5T7sVG8KC46VxM9Wb1cFrODi4ivo14mrA5vKc8VZfhc7lpW9zkut@o3l0w7ExdU9nkRt24HbcakLhLj/HlEjC@LAy7eVMfTyaRXqalacVG9uQY2x0PhxnmXSevtm6rV6l2Iwu1FEyz9S00s1m8v9fr57UVv0lMpJQzim2WMq/OSWbjNje64WbG26Mqcb1S5mlWi8aiU7Pqm0XF5MMlFo@34@LI8LeR0Iza/Bq3fry6qJbFWvqa48XUnP/JdShyXMK6XrWmklhZvY93rmTSLRHPpuTpIJJrs/ObyXLhJdPXibNy85Po3zOwuOTLHfJOvpQVNqlCZZz28yM2tPBvNX8Uubm/EYWzWy09CxfSs3i7GrGRZarcjz7PabCSWC5zUmE9noWqhcmOpkei8dXM3uoJWiFJCf36Tj4vXEbHHysu7rFHQumqTT7PMJROaNVs3Pq2vPpdF36gaKoT1WJ6dV3mYGd9lJpe9WLc5VNrnmYvkgOpFhLyvYcaKd7Hn2@dr2bgd@uJjUDkJqTa9uQaTpGs1G5H5jZTscMtWNtHmu4Ull79i0pGLi0myGApdlpKlDmXWo2OQludZ6PYyp4Ruqq1GZOLLlXPz3qB@16xlZ9eJuw43rrbr00ucjIUZdiZVhrXmolyYN2Uxlh/V8lKG8hVvZmYlqUu1XCtvMNWeVIgMRxfnhXNxciVM5nnVx/aLzcX0eTIWE5fXCi8aaqFmDdJCuJMYhedCUU8/X7WoxQWfv@SyiVbCGMnC5bDcNIfmtK1LcjryHJ37rNqwKl9Fc7XGrTpsDsplQ8heh@KmmBvVx7G75nDenYr53iUlWcmpoMzPyzFLzSwK8m3z@uayV2cXQjVxWS4Yc7bLFJ7r7NRimol6tdHvlg25NISB09dpalpCAZViDbQbitcHRXbWSl/1En0ze84mSpfzSlMu@9ibfG2YC5lTw8cMxpVQbqnlL8PSLN6v3VyNWSM77Q18V9U4czfMaLMyFbV64TZvjpI1iet0Woyery1N8zrR7PqubhRGrIXu4pmLJdfohvXeZNBJdMbn0@dO5/q526pfQHPe@sRY/fqZ6t9cXZhxKSlwvWYmW0prU529NMY1KTIuaZ1mqCP5OvNccfYcumILw2KXK5cHy2VGuDTaaiI37l5n@cWwmWhR4XyF7d2FRf2ymXvuFAaToZAtzYXwrXZh@m4j5fnk3EjEY1wkOeXNcGs8bvkSaUX2xcODxSCUyU9jOaZn1NpUvuLLtjUNekHtLsaXGTPSKyuW2Yw36vlkLVvIXpSu8rdSKVkv8re3vs5NMZtPN2KXV4NR5KrDmRkmcz0Y1kPUsJQd9RjLSkzkulww8@dGbj64G92MJ91ZfFoyO0v1ip/I/TEn8fqoXVLjsfRN6zlaYcP5ayZ/t1TUUDw6T1I9QepdMkptdNtOyPkLpqMMYAKdA/kf3V5PDEEyzEGyDTW/XqrxbLPSbxkXyqAKFCrdiS5I46Q8GojhO6rG1BOFeFu5koRKpzaOd7rybeMyHJcmc5i/dnLLKynHQKs3O/XBhL2N5cF0jUSei@3B@GZabpm1aK7VKFUjVOu5lpO4Yr5Uat1ZPa5cYfuFqdWMJy7ynDDOjMr5RaabKc4KQrN94Rv6Qo2eMC200kq@1ePN@eKOTbJGWhpSsWHsOiPlOGsWbUlGJHs5qIR5pajNK5cJfVyrXoYyl/kbSRsZbOYmvfrEWovkWI4u@lI6fd4qdrJ9Kn2TzQ1DLckUaqpvViRgmYLC/@FXHxUiGoZKwKipJvdo8mpb55iLk68cPEFOnsDH23fOnUBnn@2DBCTn@WqgBcrxu5r4hPCxXQjZ2wziqeO4tXjyem8xwK2OEyAXPMeDPiInjUs7G6EuAzOvyfgoq18jgOx4kh0U3Acjjyf/YB7DF2jwr1ACm8gTdR7CG@83aSMcwXM@8Kg/9vFka8vTw21TgwRCk/GqBPz0u37AUxV@hIxkCzhfKXj3beuzJzv5gThTV8lJI65A0EWyOqdiIKZdFHZrYvz6bAaKHMiy2lj7yntUeIZLsLEkOd@DVv2Wf3yffPQfCSkXLVoyr47NiTHrjfraYCrRCq0Pu3NhsXym6WiEDkNZoR9pH5bJxVIMOSMzDr8JOsk6RzORzydy4i@eT0UO4MPjmt00HVgf7/SR9pKAH3@OXSdvpJQ@Gq@k0D7kY3wfe0ypKfZkfK8@nqg@n9fypSwf5/NgxI@c90SfOJ6I99YjeWqfOaKvV4/W4ynj6PurSXRVU4WB5jZp8uLJ7WdOyClcqw405vXt/jQVBUsztmMklCd@vNMR30bhLjH/KqesreCshS7i1t36VAIF38iLPx8mscjJ23Ss4YcPeITGieM7sV2BL5Q@6SqycEx9IPzELXB8nP742DkURqBRbj98IHGyHWnTQsumB5NPVqmCpi@czLIN8rSqy@kWyjMP7q16/d8DuYLqgkw@4TthDACzQWz27oDTgJpsjXptqjBcEtX1Piie4@M9wVNO6I@rtNWJPwiPckPO3XmyaJmc0gOXU9oBJWdg0F7nxAkSey/jQ2/EleDMbSd9GE7GOtl/Dtr0OhzB19g96bxsrHMGzQm@MNNDc8gMeUU0tgAGXvAstClvidtNs2oLdHwjD19hfRBflby1AAgWeMNYoG7Ehw8QX08jeT7Y70n00JZmO1baZDh5STW8TlMD4/AEW7fuPqaJH9wJRJEt0ZOt1CGkYl3fSR5D8pi3Bu8kDxD3xHwv2YBkfHviO8kyJNvPRO5P1yDd3ul/B8BCL08Q1ydLe7J4WfHYB3rgUSAvtsL20D7firFrEaDthrHbYzc/7RyNQn@0W8cWth3xgv5JxMoGQJH2OJ0H7zfSQlLxgF@PLRdbZdo8ob/Q3yzMcY4EFj@RkkDtYvneox389BYB0P9AldJv01eF2629ruiO/ARh2OljawOzwvQvv3yNMkcQd@WPe1xJn91C6Ie7VUObWxs89svdNu1qZ1o6mfbncY6O2dZuKx@JTT1WnTK0USF239r0a0lWe1AGIP64HY0uT1760ybm3nykj9faY8NHu1t8m4@hN9KDHlGkR/rp7iYofD9XeZR7yMnDiNzdKAs8J4w/ecNOcw0d2IU@A@g1N1/JmbAjM04v/bWV/b7aHAB9pFMT3pzYilYA0/DMIXAPebzdrts6wUZ26D624/GldfIuMvkdZPZ5ek@AwDoFGnBkW6nx1Zgoq0H7mVTQ82wo4icu5jbIy4ZNK2X1PXz6Z@hcyDhnyJ7ge3x2VRK9hzVvwNf1Rn6dve5yr6pna/r9lbu3H2p2f3IjjfRbeSJS9wlGyWOapdcHN53QL9/WQ/84znzZNN@OvWN63tcVq0ZfSeL3iODLO4z@ppDtViH0SO9wfEJeAq9/c0gihxDuH5Q2rvVPq5iV26Xdt9@1wJCqk910pNlGuEoAQ3k7l9@xuc42qtM5ffHJWhk3/o0Vhq/Ps6UCTPYTalud43SuQAbv7dj10VGEI9sp@CQ7WpjGijJZWtm2YAav8gWFJ2xmm8nIT@jTfU3reVYGk2MwEAyrEzoAyG8fZ7U2q2zzclM8FOcYvXTfOeVjNe6eQMxHJ4qMKxCBxqcjm0jEUZ90mxPsNlv2jWyStzuSdByNoKjV0wforGhrH/r4dTxCr02gD3szrTQ@nklGTq509DwZiXfUgyvLq@gYis1hT61PXRi/bgiEOYOJ9uZ8S9IGL3tWGewzPJ3TLb9sT13kEzmINvG60VdekN6TNTWnpy4sZi3wL384@MhMTIPpyiojqlMwqrsL6oAWVfulRsf45utAAh2F8cXVjjYhftnECRHEBFoKSwuq4szjvNwaTxF1eSn7TDritMhReIAv8RtXxGkPrH77xBZdM@fkdwGTBTY40S2NpDgFkbPr6F/kXzbnqbLkKSJnxuCQc0rwbGA8@HyBHbuwfSUDnG0gcXg6sXcLxT3mJArX9eByYfshoY4/6f0jZQZFXhggESh7v9jTKWguIskvlLlqejxrDVmBD69AULFPmdCJ7ygWQawTc0Huofp4z2HAjiEurij3zjyFIg7BmKJomo5Cjq6gmP8UGGAz/kO9kcvXakHnhRa2xzp6udt@zPiIIDmwznkxvePGi97qeFyg3SgfsLKI2y4vtUFO9C/hERbrsAm7wgzZafMKzyO0axDgyN2baqzhvTY4YQl53Mm5M5GXrHOqhw52FPJuk82zlS2wyrYC3mLFh29ygxcEPAjiWhxrQHFWVBQg2ubFhw07MIgcWZXvW5dv3mOZj2vi7fTAm/TATnrQTreJ2kAFhYGxATreBnIdfNnAvdCuDZj/TVkpGipdLJPTpYKasUX3yddgzSBM0uQN8Nm6KW2pXCec7iQEtlJ@2tP6dsrHnTxrAV@n39vpjnyHnJZfU7kD@3m3fLxSTgOJ5AwG55HFV1IaVGXlk738uE4hGpbGY5Xs7NjeROzsTuksiDjqJABqAt8cj932LLXB4uNWGof0mf@/uGt9TtsI4p@rv@JMxi5KZMCu03TqxI0MwmgGEJGEbabNeDDItiY8PDwCTJu/vd3f3p0emDjp9EO/gHS629fd3u29dgtnb98XSmpJ6rfiNhkyEtMTxdqhIxkpMc5XLLg1jySEhz/vZUAwTDQ0oTX3TBfeqMKbDFjk2tNoDe0pNK/gxNq2ir/Dse6/8KOVPU@czvdi98cfJOVryby8aZEXEHe6e4XdYsr3JovZMpKJiqlnRpEU92Yb4u5Ooj3FDHTwgJ4iwRnJ@yB30@VkuJf0E9mOQvcUT@SefFGSTjMc6eb7tSrExy/G3@WXxkV/TFbhKFoLGzZ1n33ZG7nLNotovpiTDkTE4EzMl4@Po1j5dRMrvs4h@Tw6fo3LCCnEjNFQMlxcEJX5LTypyzFUqCQ8QF7hnmH6Yb68v5dhxAXilFLXehcTyEXJsCcbGeEcbtCO5ZWXSCzhxxUd8IimfRkiZM1J7UliwZcMfbFIsnon9XuyIBOIGJ@yz0O4Wv3VMD4s48Gn6oU4rlTeHFV@OsqITC9VV0o/nXCgdG0i6Q/HlaNK5fXRiWFUp48bebWxODAB6@QQAC3RxEB/SW0z@ow4ooZNIwZnnJPpP49mn6NhyTD8aMhrwLdLlgia8nIeSS/K7OcVKWRbwd89mbvjuSVo2vWA7gX/GJ@l79oBO9awDNwheoxm43ghbxpNP8dDCFDfm7qbjkbTFS9E48qSlAcKjaMFCeWlKfIksV9aRQvbLuwulqTRV@HO@7fTz@xHWomB7NQY7vf5ApABJ4qAkEUmYyVnKCF8g1E/HqM57SAAXpZSCWgCiLXhchA9S4PBRPxLGnQc9@F0sIRn3r6umTL1flPWFVL3aBZT75sKmGuFi2VopwoOG24gAq8eXtm@I@i543uXbs2pifOeCBuOqHqdHsd8Eg2vSb1LIOx2jVLboe@ed0OPEgp2QCUL/MGw2z3hXHd8JwiE5wu31Wm6BI3A@3Y7dJ3AEm672uzSYH1hCYIg2l4omm7LDSlb6FmMVRcz0nLCq4uW41cb9Gqfu0037DHGuhu2gaxO2GzRsf3QrXabti86Xb/jBY4AY0bNDapN2205tRICR7U94Vw67VAEDbvZ3GLUu2o7PojPcXnuEJX2edNhTMxnzfWdagiG0qcqCY8IbFoi6DhVFw/OtUPs2H7PUkAD50OXMtFHUbNb9gUxZxS/IRWql2rXd1ogmiQRdM@D0A27oSMuPK/Gsg4c/9KtOsGpMJpewALrBo4lEIWPURMMkhZ9p@fzbuCy3Nx2SGNGtxO6XtukSr4iwRCVNhWtsYC9tuSWhOT5PUCFHLgCLHHVcCjdh0xZWjakEJDUqmE2GyEkIYZZNkXbuWi6F0676uCzBzBXbuCYVGFugAwEE3ivbELaZa5RT0SXfKTGauiWa3F1Crcu7NqlC8pVbmoBgataC4ut2lAyJ10uGzu33J7dwHu6y6eWQp53El/1ag5ZfDK4SiFN79Kg80t@8y73jQaa5CO9ql1QHqtuhtHt8v4mntxNMTVPiskd7PH83kJsIBMxEP8wngnCqjbKucCLFzc3l/YNzXODmxvT@p6SOTK@VUJ5YX0ul6l4HE37Q57m59aWsoI6O1C@3i3peDm71nKQLD6YolweRqoYLi8CsF4mUkEJCNgQPSPfauxPRAYlbzHn14o4Ysb2YpHe3pzO6WfyV/oix4ZMAnXO8txCuYw5LJOByCcioZ@QcFAQFRmEzwHEd4yyNI@iT/fFShYdpvxqgcrUZTjvgqaB90XzG8Vvo/ut4ofb5ZlY3DVlY0W7g9du2mWAebwpkQlVL6UZc1aUS3v8Z2pqGBEZhaZExRdZ1emT4oEsDv@icq3QPE1ciXM4kJZ97V5hMlc5PjndSm8k6VK3cOscsW1ovPudy33kv8ZHmYEULMb0i0QSb@SWarmcKUNWGduTSWb4qn9AplU8pDEVQ/VDxMM6PORLd8HZ8jQYz@J1lnrqhi98u3Xerdep5wS1J7@8fvPzqaE87s8W15b87wEP4iOydMmKXsVkpvGnjJZUye6pPwmWk4nug9pDRoQb1JXGiX0yaRPPmdJGkPE15DIQ2J0jwsAEQTYKCBIwKwjcz4/2DN1ed2qmagDFHKsmuBn312zh98lU4jYwkF4yRxuutTV@ADtRf63iCUOqAakmFo0fFxtquTS54H6vUNcOB3huw9eKkaVU0O34sa/PIEnBoM9kLwy4g89vqm1napHsWlQ09JWrnUsSEXvbVOggLRxyiVB0pnOtwTIxppRr1d7osaeCA@ETQj3Yi4DEWE9KHurgPXLNWSmGgvzx7B1V0cFBgumtwEKqqYiS6//50DFZbWBS5IEGsQVYnzxK5Jx84UXo9z@a4k/ZUuHVG3BOVYtV79Ryd7GjoJxql@jqXUeQERJWGlCGk1YJDkNn6eksiThzYvpP8mD4/6NMdsB/SxNOgp5Ki/vheLKMvlOSDFXKimavLJR4pU@MZY6ppdLMJvVSMF@yFfOQMKaO4a3lxhKJQNXORif0ZEix4g4BoJFjXSOrv3Dgy0r80KeZ03vW3R/kTv9sMhg/FnVALj1UPIH70WKby9JH5PBiyi38isigayK@ynv288h9BiZc1IvdbsT@vCBhvDriPgdMl1/yokei5dw0IYYjreFpc6oo1dLKv1YnjNJRZqi/fiFT9OvBvpLtEMQUynX4egdEdyB89inLsBIb4TwDoTv5hqcXXuUXahSP0G3eyXFZhOyeY96/4zkzhiLlSwNOO4AScPaHKmbTbbRYYbgYSejsQySFJor77MYESNRaZGJG6M7XLJHUeZBdJdTzMiXaa0J9d/Jpgki7kVzi0jlKuQhQWResJdHqczCo0ffxXUiRv4JYz/L43Qn7VRnI/UoszfHMnbBgpr8/TyVCFucK1iWNQ6mU@oNPSCzoNhqvDuM1/TGuQ8W5jmlEcwaOWLfL6P/y1QkB2srWGVhR@GOSLCL9Kgeyd/vafMGT1N3kqYcntc78jpgi4igFB2aVGQSSYTfhkOZTbWP6/gE)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)

### Explanation

Brainloller is another image-based brainfuck derivative similar to Braincopter.

[image]

Blue path is Brainloller, black path is Braincopter. Red arrows point to Mycelium code.
Pixels tagged with black circles are square brackets in ImageFuck, they hide Brainloller code from ImageFuck.
ImageFuck `[` also rotates IP right in Braincopter. ImageFuck has unbalanced brackets but accidentally still works, I will fix it in my next answer.

As it turns out, ImageMagick accepts simpler syntax for XPM. So now it is just a string:

```c
char*x="..." "..." ...;
```

Answer (score 5):

## 131. [Extended Brainloller](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainloller#Extended_Brainloller), 5181 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14"    ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTaxTaTbTbTbxRtRtRtxVkVkVk
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO@O6O41d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡
♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <><

>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <

>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPQs""o<
>-}

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"1
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//*/
#1"" /*/

1<2

>main=putStr"128"
#1"" /*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999 99\"    ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;+=4C++.---.
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{      function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp         v (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002304 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5299 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkiD2vBD@g37BorQ3SfECgHdKotbiVaJEkRSvoi5bGwQBEiQIQAB4XVsn2i8z3e0Je9zT7ujpGfeZ7hhHdIT9NA5HjGM6whGe1/mK8wM@f3CcWQBvErXW2t1NiUShKisrKysrK6sqUejy5uAPfzjAD13VlEVf0SzaEk2L7hnyVDSCdGZBf@ZlMxoKUxRCpY3@ZCyqlnlMHdAcTcuqIPfgnra0kajKS9GA@BBN64bWN/gxbQ14ixZNgddFk9Ymlj6xaE3any1M0/mxNpQDmHMsq30As0RDN0SLpEdouqkq/Ljb41@lRF8VqBuQbtI5Ufll/ItFC9p4zKs9EyBjNJ2rZPKl9CsMcZq@1gxTRDyCaJoaRiZoep4XhVegSQDlDVkrpcvnr5I4lj4H0nldEec03zUtgxcsWVNt3lUNrTcRsF7WQIScyAtJVkSTEoDmM1p3WiCIAfqANkS@Z4NRkmbQmIUejxRapgVdp7sKPwgKtCIDbIFN0CKyjl5CujIw6bk@BgymNha3STRpVRR7tKmLgizJAimdFueWqJpApRmkZWFEz2RFoXuiAhk2JAl@QEZPzK0om4Ag1dMoGj6C/qoC67tDEWBUccUEUQfuIRM0ZDZwZMWLmcHrOhAJjKwD4ZY8BpmRLbdJi7wpo1RCFlNUe4R/@lpeNZpXt2tJT2We5oHeiUFwm6KBjRAkeOmBaIiAkl9LjGdmyBawANmbpqsib9ANQxS9u7K7UyQUpmEJFlYkSJrv9NSdrxTc0Ix2jiCvW9SBEW7cXFI8HUzRh08n8E25XCdUvpyjvxw@YNgWVWhq3fDwXjr1G9pkHh5E@M65LtM3XijASgFXFJrRdIvhAzoQGLCAQIbHIIYC01BQV7YKpk9ftcWWcNlQPWgNuqjSLT@pmTAxDOyOG6byI6i0oql94CdU1pioyA@VjrHQBIIGvclPi1PgmqbabaTNCIcbAxkazcQm2eoAtlIhDAW1ArLncHRVrqkpEwIHOU0LBRC4AlkRY1GiW7TEywpmgXREZVNtiOZEsTDPRO1hy4PSEHtBekWGoPUQaKxNoTgekJII6EvjrR5IiAJgaAiNVBWTfvev/12v3wc8aUHQjJ4jri26pwlE/fGEWNApNAqspvIKIQvg/Fi6nR0KmPKK3OMtLF5dOEUQIkipM22i9GgNCjRmMnStAT@F7ihJomCJtpDbGtNPj/mRrTdkW3Kh4mO@Cw1LCiBlk2oH6M9ZaCVBpA6IzATGE0tK0AE9T7tN5ifPp2PPp48PIhDnDXqPDhmmfwICFzwiUXDn/prktNJbGg2Ui8Wbmtyj9IU10NQQHRBol5DSdFH1uHdwuP1uo@v2BlGfebwnckoISrLa87hBxjNQrtt7IqSEe/n48eRV7u0SAcsMsWBvFT2C10WBxiF9YsqMeVkN6gu6FXBCW2ma@YQcx@TgVjTy5XXc1I44IAMGiqWG8gFqKGgqoqh72CDnRS2BcHurjQn7KvoKh1PhY/nR5z5w@7arTjBATXcqin21IWuotRR9MAEdDUxRTR20t4GiK/AgPCYqcQtGbT/dJWJNND8oFqISZ6LbEOku6NGVGJEeafc4zB9APelg2PSgFdxuhxZ7W/0ZdAF0act8o5QVbQYFE9pw@AINomLhfB@aCDLbFUrbFbJLJDG7VRupoFcQW1ekE4GuDH0Bex2odkf0t@oI4OGQDQPY7L6ypYLG/AKwCPaQuOk3tCxBlxqDljAWtCCi6gEdJNrjChYyId3QBHsFLRc2EIpGd7vam55mGUw6cAe6esl8tUNh5dM7VgIMQJI4oxVe7U/4PppMKmThBUHULUdfQU1MCzTS62GHRAacMTRoDqjDz6/LJmOJM7pulYG63m49Z0TkUck4RlNAAZ1K847ZR/dkA7STsnhdOgBMXxXu@hlBdgj42fUOCStDAIRMnIvCxALlBoI8G8jCAGQXqVNt9WiPRa@Lh6jt0kHBB6R10UgMd/ZjiAoy6ygk410UAWzRt3hgjEVUZzsRpPG3I76OmTfHexBraxJhPNiKDTJ8EGTPYRpYT3W03GCwWZlKpGetzbk1P4HB0NWhm4KwDCxLN49Bt8vWYNINQrMyDWNRtCoqtixjGQvZ0uxwV9G6oEtN6EzMqgRGmHTl@asakbg1w4cmNQWjSTLpFIy2zxMQEY9bMkHLkfgsAm8luYi2JSjsXxcAEqAgcMojmUR/FkAD1Beq4HEFidwHoYe4/LQLe5nLCwHMteZLVhujyqDbZDBH6yxjgJqRQLU4iproaX7v8LRW2MQWc7uDQ01WPV/cHz9@dB@7z0Adf/z4CUKnGPqEIR@EPpFQgIQQLoghksNPQph6T3Jg3KP75X6Fee59xGab41CylHUPf398HH708/eccw3h1Qt6CdQQQAfwAnjc3lQKg16v62wGFQ12Jbv2NZuzPSINNVHtU@Jc1wyLLldy@adqunGRcjET02AUucuoMBg@jaG7wcTDtSc/zCBW2SFY0zQrRRoM4wl0AYCcmRVlaRPooDBZkMeyVSRTFUVF0d402io1C@VuEFRl0aKcoWMj8Thr2bQN1IPAF7cnMJKhjdfqyKREYaDRrsOwCw3vnckjjtFOagRTJ87UcSs@jvFjnPYFBaovCHRAs2/XkQ5gAgFxKhiEmRfV9/kQkkwN15EOZJKgxOlh0OiuIr9w7AvGr@eGW0p/G@O@9PczEd7smcw6hcawxJ7WFZV5LBIQFSlozZdBVAuxCGVf6EDvPYg9ean5cl8GyoI@HphLrxJ4g7IpbMDAUoJ5BF2STTL3325Oat0RHiiX3VHDu0OGa5MS2th3@41S1zYWIrQgCCMN1eIm9AQWWHQHBcyp3@aUZHNAfnZA31D0NoXkNsddifzsATh2DB0QfZx1I0succ6GtpamwQx9RsDGmqrZpACrZJVnauQShPFxHz27w9AOMV1RmsA8junKKoa/ARZIJgik1O3K74ECX5D01XUPmDHp7mMbCNfgjaVC7zDemhiWIvac63/74x40wNvmGfALmH8Io3XgCfiGTRWQ3m0tJyvekJ/9LUtghhNF5gkbSOhbKAUe54i8sg7sR42qlw4EBrwBjbtYNS4IJ/7AMPoVObMpN0Rl0hNX1/2FEBbv2kN2blUekxrBFY07Ml6@k/2VNWfnxzm2oWh8j2Cx1z5kcdPadruIc74PlWO2NBJowu@gc2V00ZvFDjBYrIn9i@sb32pXWcfv1/qrA8lG@S4nwsyQ78rvcBGJiL0n13Z3QQMjICn8yA4@YXB/Ve3KGHK/D4aVc30PDExemJXovCAyM3J5V8WoE1O3mwJDX8FnKPbveyCrxdh14D1AqKZCfn6N2BFBEKBvIKm4vhjYYpH8iqkK312gETb49fKDBZJxFNRLSvD52DAOqesJ6WYlU9ffz482AMmfTO7PbS96EgSCJkmi@K0@C@OOPOaVQKi3FXxXBa@M1k1oD@iQn/Jgziq8CQJiOWwWp9As5OdrQotDiTBReGMT@orIbshZrTu8N3Xd5NFlQVNkRzJXN@/pwtfziA0aXNYmP5usePeWvz0w3XGYDqxD@zu0Jlg4fXxHjr5DPdkzN5wbbwlGUHuPd4I2w@@7vXegTUX7d/@QtdxL1Xeon4BCJAOmg2@z94RviSuuQ5Kf/Vwc7aXKEpS98cf0taYZMHU36VCQRQNHJYvnMGArij07bRQr78u0KSuaSdfJ79d4ASa/adq/@6V5m20yrwaEgd3H1uH92fYSRYY3Ok1@32lcXulrSizRZ3j4eVcCJoaEWt65fq@GW2sojvumhlqbO5rKOdd3VfsI/r8lHGRZ1MAFiK3gV6yoferMmbi@X0GYEeAS4P7KFdgEyRlk7Hnaew1gCIMZv1hd/xGjx3vcXY0e@oIYy2DNYYZkAgKWYRvQ/5jSIl8vrfd9OuoN2vi3KrHVuCNFBI1Nft80KR1iuV@Zg2PZ79dYkjIRJ@JeDVLpDkUQm6/pju8ninWqceisbDDAPNwxXUMtnangd1GN4znefVXh8IoMnfyb1sxeVaODha3j1LkKgSoG3mbsqxN9p3G3eFebqLWvc26gr3q21tshElN@rUZKfNtm2jHDTZF89yuQY/QFgAmvNgYbQv2O9neQkkUg@3cHMYnZYB7KuB5lfBXvMb1eqQT7FewRaFV5ZAZwUev7FE/ovZk6AU4mYS6mitYCf9/j9j5F2tU05de0DujTnoxmGhif6DrwrVY6puuLcRcsN2GzjPodLbCaJgK3cEr8bsNWAaX1nTjDb1f1vjJKba3x7S35XFPOTs@@0eg17LtcMBGMfxVwtdzFrALvdEGCLBkMf4/5o69sWrJiiqus9rrqxrXh4JV60RfAGLkXMIWBOBbJ7VcMer43nJiry7tAcw2/e5KDDFnzfCefLkN/VvF3Zw13JVGWpormV5lAarVaO93LzeKY74uFb0rOZgEB9xIFQ94J7l9KOLZFXYBs31AL9rROU0fiwlxd9xu/CwEacDL@KrZ9nVbAdcpv9tIgs3e9@Bs2nDrQBupAHBiMaQibu/d6DIigZbszfb3l1AFvjnDzNHCbrVa3Jm0Dc5u9iqYo39S6GVBv31QPoMXRb6kHsd@J2dnrII4s671O0@944ECcbDj@FubaqemgqAqGSHY@V5tr9AHux07GMHe2NCNIEziPh/f5vF7KzoTTr74KYCso4laCe822x4pJw6TYIrCyRN/f04df5sfsMfdCp2jXsYt@fLSxkl3P/Fwn/iA1O@v9If@YOnQHAu5D94N6TLNuAioqYA3vBeV34CSZXGw6N1WnVX5MtrcxvKrpib2HDpNUdFMZ8GpPEekmqHcyddcMeyfYdjdo4Grtf/37nuO90xehkmPZBOunr6LHmTYWB9rsk12uU3pa13n0/kEcswEuR2LpgWyaNmeyBQqNOO3AHLpZaCQcHwDHJw5uqtjLt6iwGxVHFvRMsexGs6npaaItFk7B61yrSgmaMhmr9EzuWQMzCDNOVRCJj8F6owlCCKZaBspZz08X6Z6Iq2U9JIyoU0XTRmQHDSn5r39vez5AoowihOFV8cTxaatEGocI4m4gCNoEqF4hWYqG5oB4kMnQwydoiIBQi3a8lxYGPHHJAEkMrBwSsBjbKSGbrtOBPO1Gxz3cOT2RJc9hunbeumcfU7@hx4z43/6Y8X5x@Ob6IRDnTJefXoGcvKBcbSezkLxJddOuw7nLqRa6iBGPqLVQOf6eHgyT5lo5GIyJdxmRO3FGHAzIVqCKCgzdtlQT@gfceglqu9OkDj0Te1gM1C06it6NMNLwELL90YijDm6WY5bDOf0LPUBZCQg0F2XhzmaIgv4Z41RmtdcR3t6OYnJid0IWZ6ehYCicItU5fEqByYAhQ@xp6C51/9PDPMQGHubx/CNjrpjz8DD/gQ3dAvc0A3L9yGAHypdzXw6DZ@wvv5gwDXW5Xtwn9vYc9PLDL9ViNV9vpBvNOnDzxa7sQUEzxvxGU6As6AovQPdRiB8asMWQRfPb2mOtQdZ3AO7x0Ic8fYqeql7vOmEN6rDaFXAd2sE1CIxk27m/kX1fflPcSn8L4GgmSaYdLUpXiSA5MuM2tzWofyVb2C7Y3Segs1ccwR3XPaqQ8MhFp4BLAeDSd/KIfltLuwU/kQhoxm8z6us49qEAXm0g3gIgk9ZlYX3tdLtyeyv/8s9QYx3GtX9qjQmOr9YYIb5WYwDcZCM5CuliqVnL72YCcdo4HYOpYKDPuET6lu2@aEuX5rjKrTQTDDwD26GGVza61aSnsil3FZHIm4QjgwLKBbsj2aMxUbvQqMiCdFoxQZP3eqCaugsLNRuo9CDZlbe35gMq7ToAZgXXA62fdlEIa6beukyB5prBFE742c58SOAIZpPa4@L5IDK/@9f/znbrfLAg/KdOWILwv7LDPzHIoLeuaTaNa9YgW1rFKm3CcGlXfMzPt@qEIxaOiLI6EWl5DBycEoYguE3spr4bPJ77FvATGgGYiaoXtS0pTzQePeirdMwwaGD0wQYMkp1dcQ7tAMqauC49T9DNFgYIJhaNRTgGiAxMVwgDso0woNsIvd5jkDVqKuupn7sCfXp6SrtMmMqLqdiJzUjmkP8p7Pp5TeghwFK2LXJPQx7IsskBaWdONs8h7@O8mBW7nJtz048nYGbY7QIjlYcEAMSL0arDDxcMhZrDKmh0VZxbRJ0vVjYWGDgqcUERbWfrFaIAILJxozfoa9ndbBmiI8WWNAe3m8HVRrA6gh279onO/U/0g/WgPjpOwTQIzH/YI0gqhP9sj6fwWnrSb31UPa89TLE29Oe6quEmcgGopT0hJhRmuJh3q6e4HFRAL/aLXwAl9AToWYIoDzXdTGfzxctKtf7Gx5JAul@DuWn32anvIRD03z@uA@5XUr9iaqbA1K8zhRUrt6narMYgxGZJ5jWZ@0p7Tek7pbft/dq3ZZOENwVx7PciJnOlQIGsWr7FvklltgCz9n7Sm1I93i8v94@nZw/qwZvif9nnfn4QPELhgtCDSZzP3fQenVNc7UI38NkgM7hyaAq5Ng9XrN217PtN9Puel@snjTb@l6v9bvS@DJ0xPXHKqBNFoYLv7IRD3YOMXRRxPbQJW9ELumZFKoekbgoUqDe7idvU0E5d3j4U5XigrZlUsaenxA2cV2FmYsiCDW0SBW1PYonPMkxjitZm5gOzKZxQkwnegkxmQFWsd@d6Mlk74I2Va9w6pS6O5UBjRQ8qjo03JSgy9BKEmf9AkbsnfOp@Tq/9ub7maBk0dUW2POjhOA/iJBFq4/FiBbhTRUQHydPko@ONSa@cJn3E77I6AX5VNZ3eTMxz4ipUg7kZnZsAchADkb6cjAFOIpeaiKOESJe1AGQGPrpXRNxDKR6nDsFxLwqlBwfivCf3YaTxeP2gkn7guI3HJu/1wYTaDXrYZtU5bjtuM@ZXeZlucYy/54Oy2hPnHnT/P35E7kC8e9aeur2uNzJAXF0dv9fea5/XlbLgLafXbvxFXymEZHKtCHb7TjIZHJgU@tvBvAJKrFtGCYIwhnqkMa/TnglxGjbpIE1uPQ8e1W9ahpcOnOF4NqNV2ucjMxK4kIQgTXJKJCQruNDmwediPEwK2hljTbWHl6Ws0/dcMPgIYVKIlz7ENYUsmBs4G/dSYHBClmOCFgZg@DtGimYw90KK7OshKZbCBQEDoPYmk47cH5AOCLwgtabPfqQ32mDTA22uJpPHTmvsqsMkDWJxukdjANo9am5lcQJ/Hacp4BoqMYDKwlRTBoXy@UpUVeivHpCZMfROmp@AkBle/@qhTP/meR9SwoFN4oXjhQWE7j4HlHd/UTSwZw6ZEzKvPXmBcf/nBxz4JWfoXzB/xASZky@eQyW1YMAY8555Dgcpzhc@8vkO1SPPoYrmyI8/4nT45RCsnaegK@iaA1DgUPGegDyDdZQ6VE8O@VPPYS8VOiI54Nbn836BDL8xmeCXQ/6FOfwRrAk/xBh27/Qcml7sDmwwyL0AfdhDDhk/yMwXj4t2kUcqsfhD2edDGoKHT0jAb5iHuo@MKw91hsy8Txwjl@mPV2pk11ZZt8SbR0RtBjrRx2uNHiXetPZ6/NMKePsxoD1p@@yjP/zhgIvBJOpTLOzRPoXCH48O6IPPLubIZbi@POSm7nteCgWfH6ujavXW@@BxH2QrLi7iQov9J5o@YqgD5oj9Jc4wP//8M1if9P1Z8Cz46L0PuB/vPfOzePzIH0sc@T@7OXsSDRMyjvN6QiEvQz/U6Yc4zx/5IqHP6oksy7rZ68FXG@BDaWCJpVBKPsDHw1Xd7mjYXf8J/dw/ffoIf@QfPutb/P1IYpxoAvL289FLe57n1MHZ/Ls/T/CtZEiwxXBc6EH9gA8Ixz5@/gB1Fn3kc3z8mUxkaFc84dK0zwhNDw44LkprBzD0zUW6S8/nAfxQB8LBEpK4gwX5e8IwxzX4Bj@Hny7@zWsW/s1bI/yjDn6TSvm@8zNfh4LBp1WIOvj59OfUP@FDHcD84@Ds7PHlxRe4D/504js5wS/@Q99dBU/Ixw5B8Y@@gO/0/vQ0eHY2Pws8nt1TB1@og/kLdRBygaA9HFEHqflpjdB4nztzqH12ptQlCJ8GHu@rJTCbG/7QaeAgVEhn/aF6M3PAwV10c4uJYbyt5dO5ShOgq6V8up4/L7byzSrEm49PZ58/@4LQAJ@DZ49AyfwH35kvZVkWffd0FKS/@nnaE7JvqYPc2bzJBE6B2JITUyPFBB7g7sELhf1CHdwf3Hs@hT6FWIWdstyIG11rlc1/pQLx8pwdagY7YAdcD@RhzopNdsEu5uxYq3yuxCoRrgf3IvyxYwjKrDRn@6zKqhy3g@z9/3FFu65ogE@DbNactRA1K8G1X6lcAzIJSh/Cn8yy7ByonLNT@GcVIqDcT08sqbOXfXig7mnXzyJ0/CDnDrLuYMztlh@jMf35y0so9nxPzIJo8vFenMvWo4v2u58e7pPJpPvx5IAxHx4YWxe6QhHXCYK8vDw95dKN9NMTg6sk89ND32df4DN8Ume@U@fy6aB3hpwNnn58oNyeWbvdxm97Np3ZIRKw49rrxO0bEoDP9J28u4H5flnweO6jj19evF7vhwf3iduuicdDi2Dselzcwzwk0SGXl1jBSRhCuDAaKrGo9@wsFoX7WMIb8LAk2c7y4NJ1/cEVJLPqIHG8SKXShsEvCFAERrEHF288PbjuQ4@pVDJKoqOBZIzWjEAy7HV5vT9xp6dOGSEvRLvcc5dmuOkvL9t/ni8vpx7y8eKf14uRzu@Z1wPJ3ijczb945qeeUw/GQRTm@vJyhkEC9wVC9x7vo/flxY6DX4/31MZ55gXe4dLBP@O/ZtKmTrsPXg7Q@lDpSNTr6S5EbyTmSfiSzl/qI1TA4wq7w1Avl5t3399/PgofxSP3nx6PHo88p0fBo4ezxx3d7nUf0CDLK9lLcQfIN@ogeFJzcSGXG2XxBPcANEUMKlqfDidPdoXB/eQ5ev1JcEnfke/z/VEyaZd9dPTLR@g2gA4Kc8HnAOSX9tCnZ6drodqg9J7B9wvtMBnCL19Azuw0MGY8zir/w8OcJf3RS590U4dfDviXE4KffnG5T3bkleD3uE/INpDri@uQN@65R9eL6/BL9wWtviPOS4yLaOTk5Chih@MJCHNHXntlM8rC3SoMKaLJC6TnnhygOLmB516oVaor9mUVLL0dJvmi0SgTgt/5D7F8aE6d4HaJvTfjCrjsDkQnkgTfAW2aSQomFl1o@RkdZ2H0VBTeoDVJ@mjHwwyJ7ooiGKmiouA6H04gwI5WejOYtH6kDkDRgPlsivAZV3lxIoqzyWQmrj9Z2Tzmh7RnCBNg/Pz@t3/1L@D79/D9c/v65/9HMoq/v//t//y//e5v/hYi/wt8/2/4/uff//bf/rH9Jff/AN//ZyvuH5zvFpz9pQDX//D73/7F3/3@t//qr@H7vzrfv379/d1f/if7//91/jD4t7/7y3/AH/sGcP3Vn/3u3/4JkPiXGP6XEIZ/J/pPIUj7AvbHt5VO/3LIgglGP/yyifxT@heGA3VPM@tIwPrvf3lADzXOhlzh/IVhOYi2If/s97/9N38HsTuQf7LK/pmGuNeQjjisCvpTgPybHTodyD@l4nSzCj@14vlFY@vayKezF1SMzlTKuVeXqAMUpUv5QmN9G7dTV1mjaxSdfKn0@ta5dLQJLfAoXiLN07YS5mECjMd1BLHTUtTZl8ApdVbPNyC5UaETCYi37@d4Hw7hPXVWbWJEsUwvSPotXqvVG9Pl0uA28EJR2BM@0tG43x8MBuEHr37yIdfg4U8rEO59E@WAusZ12iRnb5vLmANChpjEjULoQDOV7NN28QHyif5@JFwwCoOG3B/A7HCmrQFM04Shcz2UvhlY29QFdNgxPoWJj@tbOEGQJZqlgti9Q6FkIppIhkMJfyKZiES5WDTq50J@Lp6IJ1k/TA0SXCwRTXL@RCQZjkQiST/NhaLJOEwk1Z4sMQwYi5zLRZOArAr42NEpPr@lBQdn1EFPlGB2/oGee3reDwe9VQQ9SdCucOKBpV0M4@Io3Ec5mqdcoTBgp8MszdEuyrWkBfqAzSbCLNilXbzJJOLpWNjleiIp8MmyLlcPb@JsopCJu1wi3kQTLBvPuFwS3hQKWbZQcLkq9g1@XK7F6oZloaAB3uVjLHp/umS8yaZtuCHehBJYlMs1slPsm/HqJg5gKt6Ew4iAdrme1@gQuWEXlSC5LPuGZTNZl2ti1yIBfy5Xg@ALw18CMqXtpAipYIYksXjrcmXtmwhBd77CgDd5vEk4NwU7BQEBnQJ3XYUXRi5XH4J9A/S0C6bLAhEjkHsIoeeUavEulwA3woJXIZ80sMRlepHuZ@CTzTz15/3@/FzAFLkx6e988gUnZfg6BT8kZdSYzPenjBeT/ippXnE@Bqao3cXbzxJTnt9NUbZSKotKr9LAD0np91cJ/cr6Q1L2fjBF0hwwe@KpwfVJAnvEtUFAUshVmc9dJyDTFPYueuHxfiFGt4c25aUIvd/D@idgaUY/TRKuWNx1fARX1ydXGIJzD826wXZwuR9cLu998vGTKx51HcP8OuD@kfsEk9ik69gVj7to74krBF0z6nLF6BAI/R0Mt2I/4KY/uU4M0ZoYKh06eUEKlin2hFBCP3vwyvvxt@v94oB1T15wAQ/IfPYsfT4/fL2fkGIwmWEW4D1egJHiPXmB7s04HR0CFHcaAj2KOVP2wh9Ag9iuAWwNs1YRNMwOgkEavjDPxnQ9ZbPD40p6aGIWJB9cjtVkL8d43O54yO32uk8AyUfataVXvSeEZNpmrWfFHxdwBPiTBCPfYYInGQATlA4koQJvSDJGx6bFG7g@R0o8pl2xpAuj8fyo5Kqwz/4A5z8@6kZPz/47yjaJYhx18EL18KmlSJI@SZ7g9Bls9dMzJ88VvYj3fRdbJJ9Qh24k2h3emb0ckN9DHHsPAmEtoh0cHh7CnL5x5gq7KsGnU8aZe58xZNL9cHbiS0WyPjKRDa4m/2e4wvHmE4lQhojOID08RcqeDSWiyJo@bR4AuhPfP@YThHJTgJQ6QYPZdaCj5AvKAldY6Aeb1tPfHJDpEl394uzNT1SyfXB8jYvFHv64Tp4NvX@kvb8py8qXRDhwRlbbUNRoaKuXevKn@E@Jn66blWal8Jk9ThwnHh6cBvFzbs5NmP30GcYiuZanDsxfvFqU@416eXJwrLvDEXcYJvmpA7vaXNx7cBaKB01@cfDo@LR5InGUNrgnxnOIow@k9u5ntnMzHZOFECgq8Ue9fl8O/dH1z78cMozbTdPcYew3gVP7/xR@6GzFLsQVi7q86O1n/vT009MBDUYw7QpFUZp9DG2buRujfEp75kfqT0cq/IlHJvkTRXKrHp2eQZQJEc69iBCi94hhmJsQDOPJZCwRO6D@wDBf2ymD1PXSsSSKhjkZ71s7ThvyNY/r6up6/RgC15OlaMB1da7TarynccDHzREc8bfjHCNgK4och7YbtzAZ9M/BWDC88OAscp4eLaGK8OA0zyJ@FvQRHkaHbohe6gv1AXBNBIu49sDPCUV9QB8TvPWs4Pz0j6blxf131kt9@OCoPNMKmtYTIsdMTmSAO6HA7gP28L2eSeOyPtlOt30XefTY0HTbQV5Z0HYmk@h023YhbodY7hbBR7RkUwG1OaJJiYRyrJxd/AcbrDuRkJRCsZSHPHSKlsj2kJPbZXTxJBNSvY@S1ymcZiEKsSA44RQBR0BAB5Eegts7RgdJwUMgfTSH6RLZZgIoMOX8hBI/LTkZ7/H2EbIjeklQNBMQ26V77BrQR09OsU4dViMJVgJYiLUj@pkMN0Zf8Duth4@M3z966S8rNywPptKndGjjJ@bggsawTwwkGYVxzxYcckSMw2aCjXv0Q9Oe2O48njWcE7Nh1At1ZPnHJ3ZT6SfUlUfwfsFtiJPfjH/8UfhJvx8/nnjHKQuvPt8YhouRR7ZBjqzUOAXiod/LjyfWvc8nP6bG3isP3sNIBOPrCyXZzDa9Tt2g5moKaMGtStPrX96rgd@oj/7CveoDkif@o7vU0s@nWP8cvnKK8yv@5xTn1APKtFJLn3rCn8IXd0R2XKVg6PTxJztRmGXkUVLLe/4xBfxQIKPPV4DKAJ3mveLzPXqhcAUS32Y8UX78kfcpZ/MTJRDwItRP4U@FewsCj74U3h97@NP5p@X9BPIfe@CagmIULxAP@Rxev6xpB/pOgMd2m25It2mcI3lzIG@cSh3dfTq6O0p9/Li8nwfGj36b/cfsRhqQ@DkSf7LliuY5uvPSr1hCll48rh/k4x@CRybt8stgyhzd@fWtnDaFR3eQosPg51D9gvqSHGS22m1DCXPcp@yjZMhhFGS2Sc5bM8kZk1YPHUkhb9oUZNkBtz2AdRnmaTw@yOCnVU0N8AQC05yDFTHxYf7pE7Uq2vHtgZJRuXRxegvzPXKuloHrQOSQTvvRhG/p131qeKVz15OvevEuT8NELxzb6q5ENZEOZxrCPYKgGvjCvpzYGsv26AJlQ7QHwBDtgXAB1CLIJEdPOJApJxFaa9VAkAv1hGS74eNZJibqJ1Bvm54PKsQmAzrzHjJk/zBFdBPIkwwhWj4l5UEAugr1ASqBNGAd5Ef6DBQZ/eOPtHN7moLpZRzHAgRDuKGPQ6A3lELh30Ep4EAqhyCjqA9JIUDbB0xBP8SdgiL/tIIcN2IPZPAN/bY3cZB4E3smqmk70SPfvDYZ2BYfPgzBXHQIgn9iLkN@SHv5w4Ez3B@DsXJdbTbytet0HX7B7E9szm48Xp/y9@a4MB2PAevKKvG6E/gaJ3YuBZgtgOUHIqX18AzPHn3ZLNGhUDnnxydEgfUH9voNDKjHa0yiSc7dMYOa0Wdm8khmdk/5xfMWiYMfOVM4sDp8Eckhg7Oyce3fePabuNYCg7nzWNvO8a9j0TSdU9ACq1NgyUm35CGHMfrqQy90Tk0jvhOr7V/ibIBLoH7iwmLIfZkc7TmwEezkJwdcWXZ20j8oPO2sx1s8SjSVhIn6Mc36McCtAqFVILwKRFaB6CoQWwXiq0BiFUg6AW6FmbMxw@wsHI5tgvFNMLEJJtfBCLsJbjBEQptgeBOMbILRTXBTWmRdWixB8NIHK26SrisamMZFEqs0fDRHtUhkFNBwryMjQGjoDSRkj7yJhPISu5HxJOsUVGQqCBQKxTb3oH1WsCmPTZXfpsNvl2zfOZEwVlH2TIcIbN4wQCvl53gWIwid95hGV2WKArVLC4rIgzEgWmClpAog/6L32H6Ex1gcb9yVEUOKW99Ddjz@DPJw5FhRW3z2JIf2JdvYQnux2c9A0WvGbPl6O0TaVB7vjLQ2xshO3DbWj6hgkaPvQIRsCGyDXefwVZkNY7K3yPDXi9xBuLfIN0TZeKP7ciFvPAR5apWVjP8EW2pVnm2niKS1wQxwzpAmMvCqQfFZrtQX7tj1@9/@9f9O//63f/G39O/@5m//v//8P2H4P@HP/wk2Cx1aA/z5X@DPv8ef/wV//gZ//nIrE4EPH7t@99f/AW7/x/9I/@5f/IWd9G/@zuWPrBFBCkZtcv7Vv8SfP8Gf/8vlj64B/@rPbEDM4vK/UDumlQeg/vy/0DSUhljWyP7672na5QMDw@NI3r3dxx@3nvywEazZcE9Cj6/T7V9hYCDbWa/PBXidO25z58MG8G4hN3g8FHnT98CcsT0OUUsLvDBA734nSjPR/hHQhNHMYB/kbdYDo8dZInBD7f97@ph2@xAGoskjbClbhzv1d@rt2qQirM/FAHV4dKGDCsPeNSUwvaVAvslMYGEGcdpCZqScLSMOf8t46PpqAHGtJEu2PJyXcspa5YZJD@2cXQv/m6kuCi0OQ/YjYOQMacpxVOe2CtxRN6@aDUp5HQNTxs1DIdtZSYQ41qFJINua38hYvCFc8L9Gt2k5p9vkK4VXHQY/XTAxR9saaV1Qina5vgGLnHbgvWhxhXfhbXodgHv2OPy484jJPmDX7e2ti9qKY1GGjJ6HYNiqlK0y1kncblJoKym0lQQ02ziJromGQq9oIAMH6sXdx6nsbFsqajfbRriw56zaAcmAuaC9KOiXlIk5SL1FTTTyrrJ7i3wLJfeYcvrJg0p0zhnt8r7JADh386Ret@V@1OwbmLcNtT8ncnsnZqe13se0k2erUxDuUa@5tG45Lrmv5XYL/Apq7tH3nQWF2H9iQYHvLCgW/XZBr5sV8@6gf5@/31Y7KzWx1vAbZHbHP9gZoHBo/GsQvY06QooNEvR4YcqTdqY83ZlGe/acewzxzOqIiJ3Djo2tgyNwElPWLNFeHvisazDl0NAK3nqzwb7XkDgvEuirmiGa24@OybYbvurGhxcFra/CqObHoypk59ht3P21H1PfHVfWI5tjhWbtlyUgaptRaHk@PcmqbD09gfGpSN4NA/E2KKBvtJvCtyxAaCu/Z23aVnSPhkfsWN5v4yT2rp2tIQsjT0V3Et1QSJqGCZ0gKjD5oge8MML3hRCWYBXJg1xokXYtjxeZONDGWl9UNXxuE3O/Ql/c4EaCeF0ntPhp3k8LWxQ5k2iP4Oe9TtarX52Vvgp5eO86f2gXwQ4z/LTxmsfIWWNPcU/vFmdnW5VX//X01rfprX@dXkk2TOs1zSQSV3vw@uuKDns2GABwQ0b422T4nUe135CzQ8o6Gs8TtzN8N4k90RRg@ENK0wCadsCDEsiHf31nwt2a8NZ7/P96A66y57@3@YgxW1@Avhnn0fYjUzSTHFShCqIHwIte1D1vi1uLdu47y3ImOmSG56ddRHGp6GIPHVPXRdVc77euEH9D5tEt5Y3cE1@VlJ24hyZj6qdHofebKPfUExV@IfY8DqR/C@@qxjWR7xF99X0VR0VHlJ5mHyLvYf3cjilGHoUiQMfviAzvn3q974uVDSKvpYdsxhEKi@/zjyzcvVbNuAiasvdANAM06AE5A4GcPKEv9IX9@KRiv2jG0aP2@GO3ZBmfKv0mQ4AP9mtEOP@mWO/X1GfNs67Sd4wIa9jgbpXxCakVRnxG6W0b/joWfbumZJVhnSm1auUd6@S9Fpe/1uJbUrGSSdsq@T6R/JbQfbfMbYmajWyjwrK/bgh5gznLK4ogeLYx2jFfbTFNfaMTMA5bTFPfGVWe9ijUdU6i6Sw8Ijhl2xdeSoZgEa5TuLbgighhDvpkC9SqbmjXrpa8SMqY17esFifmXkBbdIuL3u19xC0oahXGhdyXdZnCu2UKb8oUdspc94DdIreAKGGnSKcVsHm@1gSKKFnvaGdMwpk7XL6mtuGjaryBe69f3LL7WPbT7qn7GBSyW3Qf5z2glN0993GOBEz3cZ0ERu7jKwhs@pb7F/fxqlsggAG3JPAZ4x0VjveC@zjr8b5Q5PViq3KD7uN1mwLMJ/uWcOTFXl7tOrv@2npVVRT9tlHpp1FiTLhoWK37Rz/5svBPQJ2DhSDxY4oOHRFgnIDsDBpbI4ZdDgwbQfL@Is@@4eN4tTTlrG9s1lAg3ZfaWlRBKZkQfeQ@cO8qI5swTCWLj3AFAlFvHu@niObezMy@RY5TOkgoaeTd8gn3gsQe6HlI@j0Aby/iKJv8q/baRWE34PfRiZnfo/MNOaviCEXoDODdQxYy9Wf3VyqFbf3qkBq79bdb6O0aATZiYAVitxJBu6XTwYZD25QUpmv6rpCQVNztk7fz4MfplCi9r7IRreD0zHeSSbRTM1QM253f@7XqbOVD0nZUECbes492L1uPC0QXY9JG121ZqnbnAxK2dE6PPF8uotjmnCCBs9WNn4wV7w1Dq7x2kURz7apJyBzEh3YmvGWXvtmXwUd5ft30dZUTTHCgERFs5VyXYutX7VfY75ptv68M6hUTXhWwz7DeP5S@Na@/Osq@olzZFPu2ATHRT@e8e42jdQkblsPsYMsy/5qsvTHx8Z0RtpFvF7rG/sraX7FtPSf4Bt9ezy1sXGglGNPdyBEuzI5C7zPqrUWiTIMroyWIJTl47IqvKd1U7eu02hXf18SYgmM0XH51Axu7DbzdeIiPVMB4xXK7l@M7tsg@xbpv45r61s6FveugoZfY@silrUhQ98R/be2iBRGVp1quUi51YNCNx@Pet1sR2Gsh72Ycp766TbCetoT8eL4GeU0n@k4MNMP6@KC63rqUkQgwBniyb2OLn9PHvY4u29Lnr/ou5LNhtzjq4BptugG/o5XQ1OFxyJYdvlrAENHyHPEOkpV5C/z2k9ka7hqhdOCGztMTGb6entA55@nJGcWwadbbSH84cN6LE9p61@bBrjfTO@85xgWAydh@06OzAOc8nm77oRzgW1XXb0le55qolrxydsD1IdyiWntGeMKc134Z6yrGfmcqSKonFMEpbCiKz0DauRAaFz6Ja6VTzkfb0MGzF01dU52Xqo7sF@@SkyDN1dIrIXuiznjiBmKXQh7d3KLIdsha7YuR9ySSE2btl1Lyqr2EvOKNnxb7QbLjE0rClGMk6/bxS2vXD9NLMhGCiY8W8LiriGN8VyHI7p7V5GsZWmVQkPt9ECTGOavXdnBp4OsLA5oUyG7ePN0ib5x0jq1zfMLIkZHOOjCw07NzLoRJh2JgTSX9wNnNFxiLbjI0nv3AEictAgXfOFzidjDh38r70bPw7l651ceL@D56nrBl7QfFZGgdBURe3eKz8/zY1tK0s2lJ9MDWzuXqiBPKOZImRfYpg@ijpntcB67VwS8YtN0meEVYnZjgwbM6jqkPKlE86AFGC7ZvDRi4KhptZHvNu3ZJVekf6HCIvEEMyiNWKikWcNg7ezvYIQ2yIrG2d5@jYFw/9Fw/4GYi9eEAdaEta5h/JcoYJgfYbWSZ/uigszdUsCvbXWB1E926CcNU48Oegj96XD7A4nN5XTuYAN7Z/fhga963WUEpev/ANHqxdkFLp9ONMWfUztP99CBd68B9hi352sNInmHyF0ovnSt2F@davDGVQmyjc5Pphn3VeG@uyxfj7IWep@RIZ@y7C8@TF5FlNBvOpgX2VjovSZF49la6NcW0IiaZ6XB00xNrepczTPmqfF2uLZlC86bVvxlKd@32MK7WKb12l@nfzMWbRFudtprJonkjtrJla1QeWhNuUYm3Y82ZamZajczgclGcjebFmNaRo9kbMd6S9IuZsIjqwkWTups2BrH6xWKU5Ma9RTpr9jpxn4/pZDP9xIXQu5Mu69mrXt@IdqOjepIPT8eXkr4YXF2oz6Vhtj4VfPqwUIxNKbVanM7ESHvUVS7Uu1qr1c1lqrMRZ97pvWGkfT2xugkjFg5P0uJgGIkWJ5aRKGXSV3Erly62Cspty7pbtBJVyrqwGvHmpZBUfNOKJYQnuSZjsq35pXxVn8UuQg3tQr1UisPq6HxyXlX0ySgXkSuNccTo3xa6Wih0cVOfXnRKlBG5bHcStWEokRPmAnMV1bRxuJEsl4zr@STzXBHbWaGeEbsxNhO9zXPD68pCqExLtVq7qreb47h5xSl3BXZIVW6FejozKpTGCa5RXhQT58X6JJstzqfdkNTX0pNeO3x9G5uVymKxfcOEL/iJde2TsxWFGV5emotW86p4WzbvoFtfX8oRaTHPtDKG9JzLmte1ElM2RoN6ZKj29FZczmrCZbUYsYqj9MWsfZcsZkaiVO2OtFGjrbQnlpwbMgVqkR3dNLvirCAvZ3w@UmrdMMN8TbDi6X64zgwlqTtSKuayf15a9uuTbr@XrJyzOfH5qpdpRWt5nbsumJGyuqA6jYwkL2s3EjeqJi@Kd918Wr5Wo9mqqFfPL6bzUKgjS9VZdMnNb4eFiDwXImypkrm99t1chmq@ki@TqWrhSp8K5Qrn7X70yqcVxCVTkvjneNZnTCaReW6CL7wsNVXFGEcVNlFo@AZx02gnr69nXbN4W8u2BWWZuLsejWJ3Nep2WjQ1I5S4LKSTTHXEGuf8sFy8i8tqITLLnCv5ZLG9bCasfGmiJC5K/dxlzcg1xsJtMt@vLxajfuJSrJZGaUpM5Gq1Ybff6s47dbO6YK8jwrDry5/ny8996MeteiF02czE@pNauHWVU6fVRsG31G7bJT1bHnH5amISa8TDY2o6v0yk65Yq67nz62TsZiKX8ulcv5nlNFG8fRauuBFfbyzYhBk3bgq3N7rpsxpdLdIdZMKLm@sO07ozzeiFTN3N27FiemQIV725dWnGG2pIq9yw3I1UbirRaVt@7lS1YXrMXDVvl0x3tizMq5Zg1UdatBePjs7n5rOxvDKuqERnyCvNclYrDYXYVUdexpkopzY6Wela6FyG2HSzf3EtFi6m/WVTHIeGF8@TC4EXzGq60z1XYtO57pPCiWmJapTbt/348zPbFcudpJweNWvVohVq8MykUy9Fn0sd0ywIzaKcicjqJJfpnI/G2bsF3zDny0kj1lWkRdUIsXlqXu5ct4Sh1jcL5p0wXN4W7tTrSSh2WxlKcas34sYyV2pJbLys13w5X1U57/YXsdZEnApgGeo3RZ3LpIfDClXhxvFpZpE0LfXcvCp3s5dpOZ0uJUI3eih@McqeX8x7cqvZKl/0eC1y182GY5Vunw31MuV8vxoZ9@PVcjxSylKN7uKmxvVyCZkb8Ep2eLmI6MlSKBNjWrPaxc2wMVDLSjbdnkuZsNDQZvE2L6lNcRmLM9esbzhIXqppNlKNUU0rZzVLhVnYp14Vr0PVxUK47fKTMC89d0yf0FkOlpWWyGvKoPRc4xqtSSkrD4etWEZosJVMnZ0szRmvl6pUMldVuVxpPi3MBvU2a@q5Cz3RnZd72WpV7Oq9sC51K@m5xE7b7bubm2ZFHd/ejC9q8W5l2eOH0ZYl1WKVuUU9g8nTmpaahe48J5nSsDZ9Vs/nk9sWE2mej0vN3tQ3TN51pmH5tsKWypmWxE@KN/241SzP9etLRVKYcajSZ6hZs7pcWmJay5dn15251Fou03LGfObmVwxfOi/mbi1fMl9I5yqNOm8olcp5KZfmx7PrWek27hOX9eteVB4931FVVVVCxl1diWfYsBlqRnPLrDA8ZyfnmXHjspHkdK550bq@vuIGijAW4p1KLta@Ftrp9OXV4lLiW9WqXr1qNqiKT729u2swlYZSSkqlYq2hRYtT47rdjvMzLX3Ds8XIuDsrzTOz68mkPU5e@jqWyIe1pShytZlSYsQLkJ0EJU6m1Wy5ai5Cz8vhc3@a025bybR@HktnF1JvKk6XbDo39TFmYT7rxWQ9EWp05udSR7ju969qmUFYn@qNWDZKXSala7XVzQ6ukwvx6qLUKkwssd7rRmSfyerDxk26aTaFhXwuxAbTptlRoPNJerSRySZN5S6XuDJkH5sQMpTQvuarTGkQvS1f9rRZdn7dWuRgypHgpCob1RZqa5IYqRdXZuaq/XyVSPSb3YsRFDwZ3A0EuenL9LrijaSUqbvbq9YoX520mOHN7XW82rzwJZZh4/xZ0AbnfHLRWFZYVpSS/WlxMg/rJSFxnriqCMrlvFxrSmI/Vg/dKOfqksqp8QGblrjZdKYyvkU0k8j3pUyzrBq5pnARF7UqzzDz9p1Vad8mrkLn7A1bH8/YkHk9Y1ipo8qLTrnTCfWozNS80tt1bpr3XVjpTn1YE84VptyuFZfaopQPmc10OStdTWYLvbSQjfCdUDrPKlVB5sAsicb6DaM5WmamXaotzUvZTCJ@F7oACTJNJTnrRHhRMPX@fMiUricXynw4GbUM33jO1Hx3nXk0OWgNTEYolRrl4ixvRLVLc6hSsZgQumgbetysPY8XxayVG7SaSiSbbPW7lYsOc92QrpI32fpdXIxWmeKzmGzXY6xQirYFhqtp46kFI5LQH1GlBdszBEU0@Pik8hzNTya@3mI6sXz6Xfz8KtHuj7LcVOB94XRXe@bnrUuFlctxsW9W2rPpbaENFqLamjZVqnDX1MNX8oVUv2hVrkdcNV1bWkwm2RZuI/2OwUmqNK2FrehlUezHBSmXvxsNcxfF5yLbkZ7ZGacYNzfhwgVHxSVfxtJ6CtO60W/UZYgX051K4nrWW2bHg7IkXhRDOaNTi/XqV7ySh2FUfi6xeqtwXrrrdZUBI2lqpV5jWeouFsq3b2vP3LR3U102tPmF0b9MV5XwrVRUtepti8vdGEw5nincZIe1u@wiEasaSlds9BMNdew7D2sCn1ZLMSouTsVMq800RTnMxefLLj8SGe6uPRolLphlzFwyadWcDRP9ZbJ7Pubad2XtvLEYMefj@V01c8tNRB/HVQWdurGW1ej5edt3tThvFvtKsygJDD9eDM2LzES8nHVvYmlfQmcbvnyvNZiXqn29nWfi3W6Cq4fD7Yj13KsuzJsy1cqVLsLx3MKaS/nRpDxPXOjpWH0xb95EIqO74bySqMdq0Tk31Ub5jF7oRxnt1oyr88ZFv5AR89K1ZF4vu8KYii0n5WIhkfdFRb5T7dyxUp55rvcUa9CXGle34XqMEaIXlers7i6XZsZxaZgvKucwJs746/miPuyMujcVMyxTWqXjK8aWsWX97qbcU6vty@tBd9aPx6vGRWuYnCw7ek2u@fRls9jVznPVsZJb3oLAxWrJ6LCp5Jtt@TZXYyuUFWunZ2CDc5mSvOgzxSh7Jans5Xx8nrwdt2OjzqiVndY689EwVo9HtYm4jFvt5@hEbMY7l@M6I3Q7s4EvdE5p9eXiNn8TMUrlmV6yqpp4xSZCpbtRc5yfNH3j7FWha2XbrN4NtUuziS8bBasgcd1Khsrdq2GmODq/MS9uQkmqUZAXk8TwPHbuq8JgMhmalURLCSlTps0ordlUHI1ZvpzjW8a82yyUeuVeKMHoPjk@s65iz5ed6h1v6RGVocxFrDfjfRd5sCBycida97UsnR3DXIS9nYav1H44ZKq39bpgZbX4qBlOipGC0VK11lwbtkLyzXl8NBPkqyGVEZe9iNKstXvl@XLWS44iPb4@baYLt2o7nFX1wdw0uFjyKtTin6tjI1yx9GqpKWTUmzHPSzPfXMnkro36lOr1y@leu/A8kaatSCUdSS9ue2xkcjcdcuryNt8JDavd9ECa1dqRZW0WzvTOObU2lvWxEWLYRkvNjxLz5oV4RV0u8@JikLjJVFuR5tUwOQor/VG9yi5GFVkS7u7MCVfs9Es3XK8YbWVukqMLyUyL8WZSuhwy83K3chfL9sQIS/kGxTETypaE8GX@1mddCkr0WV5yZWuZlNRFuSl36/1pWi/1hs1JOXPBZLjQ9HxeGYcvakx4wmfGidyV0TEUSsxH0/Nm5TpmDu7SViuiVUPThH5Xlfu3oV51wAtjNpYAHXzd694tmulaZlbqlC/qZlrtL0WfMbtSz4uFQkalLqR2@dl85jVpko40K6XOzfNN2ug3ol3LLHLzZ5FZLNTKZVYQFp100RyVW5d1tRhnx73Mdfxm0CupTa0qh68oIRkf3cYZtS5cTlgxUk1HCs@tc@G5OI3VtJFqCY38HWeVa6DsitFmRe/MxsvsgJXm4Uj@1qz0e/od9NbhkgpNLmqdXk0aqvNZ7dJqXYXHdW7UmimjmMrrvkg@WanwXD@Mk7DoraaONeWqb93Wy9Mrg2EGy9hE1M/FK5kqhfR@uliLXYb48/NOLtnkxs8lMZS4jkzSs1Cldu1To6KeK/bHCpsd1YbijQxThnasOrxk62W52b@bZG@Tizq17HSlpHrZnmlX2dEsN5oOG815GKZXjVbJNOu1W6tXnIa6l3GlWxn0GrlC9kbI8rwZr6jZfGWkT1rd8ewiEqWGhfDt8Dp@Kfdjo3hRXHSuJnqyerksZgcXEV9HvUxYHd5SnivK8Lnctazuc1xu1W8umXYmLqjs8yJu3Q7ajEldJMb584gYXxYHXLypjqeTSa9SU7XionpzDWyOh8KN8y6T1ts3VavVuxCF24smWPqXmlis317q9fPbi96kp1JKGMQ3yxhX5yWzcJsb3XGzYm3RlTnfqHI1q0TjUSnZ9U2j4/JgkotG2/HxZXlayOlGbH4NWr9fXVRLYq18TXHj605@5LuUOC5hXC9b00gtLd7GutczaRaJ5tJzdZBINNn5zeW5cJPo6sXZuHnJ9W@Y2V1yZI75Jl9LC5pUoTLPeniRm1t5Npq/il3c3ojD2KyXn4SK6Vm9XYxZybLUbkeeZ7XZSCwXOKkxn85C1ULlxlIj0Xnr5m50Ba0QpYT@/CYfF68jYo@Vl3dZo6B11SafZplLJjRrtm58Wl99Lou@UTVUCOuxPDuv8jAzvstMLnuxbnOotM8zF8kB1YsIeV/DjBXvYs@3z9eycTv0xcegchJSbXpzDSZJ12o2IvMbKdnhlq1sos13C0suf8WkIxcXk2QxFLosJUsdyqxHxyAtz7PQ7WVOCd1UW43IxJcr5@a9Qf2uWcvOrhN3HW5cbdenlzgZCzPsTKoMa81FuTBvymIsP6rlpQzlK97MzEpSl2q5Vt5gqj2pEBmOLs4L5@LkSpjM86qP7Rebi@nzZCwmLq8VXjTUQs0apIVwJzEKz4Winn6@alGLCz5/yWUTrYQxkoXLYblpDs1pW5fkdOQ5OvdZtWFVvormao1bddgclMuGkL0OxU0xN6qPY3fN4bw7FfO9S0qyklNBmZ@XY5aaWRTk2@b1zWWvzi6EauKyXDDmbJcpPNfZqcU0E/Vqo98tG3JpCAOnr9PUtIQCKsUaaDcUrw@K7KyVvuol@mb2nE2ULueVplz2sTf52jAXMqeGjxmMK6HcUstfhqVZvF@7uRqzRnbaG/iuqnHmbpjRZmUqavXCbd4cJWsS1@m0GD1fW5rmdaLZ9V3dKIxYC93FMxdLrtEN673JoJPojM@nz53O9XO3Vb@A5rz1ibH69TPVv7m6MONSUuB6zUy2lNamOntpjGtSZFzSOs1QR/J15rni7Dl0xRaGxS5XLg@Wy4xwabTVRG7cvc7yi2Ez0aLC@QrbuwuL@mUz99wpDCZDIVuaC@Fb7cL03UbK88m5kYjHuEhyypvh1njc8iXSiuyLhweLQSiTn8ZyTM@otal8xZdtaxr0gtpdjC8zZqRXViyzGW/U88latpC9KF3lb6VSsl7kb299nZtiNp9uxC6vBqPIVYczM0zmejCsh6hhKTvqMZaVmMh1uWDmz43cfHA3uhlPurP4tGR2luoVP5H7Y07i9VG7pMZj6ZvWc7TChvPXTP5uqaiheHSepHqC1LtklNrotp2Q8xdMRxnABDoH8j@6vZ4YgmSYg2Qban69VOPZZqXfMi6UQRUoVLoTXZDGSXk0EMN3VI2pJwrxtnIlCZVObRzvdOXbxmU4Lk3mMH/t5JZXUo6BVm926oMJexvLg@kaiTwX24PxzbTcMmvRXKtRqkao1nMtJ3HFfKnUurN6XLnC9gtTqxlPXOQ5YZwZlfOLTDdTnBWEZvvCN/SFGj1hWmillXyrx5vzxR2bZI20NKRiw9h1Rspx1izakoxI9nJQCfNKUZtXLhP6uFa9DGUu8zeSNjLYzE169Ym1FsmxHF30pXT6vFXsZPtU@iabG4ZakinUVN@sSMAyBYX/w68@KkQ0DJWAUVNN7tHkBb/OMRcnXzl4gpw8gY@375w7gc4@2wcJSM7z1UALlON3NfEJ4WO7ELK3GcQT0nFr8eT13mKAWx0nQC54jgd9RE5Fl3Y2Ql0GZl6T8VFWv0YA2fEkOyi4D0YeT/7BPIYv0OBfoQQ2kSfqPIQ33m/SRjiC53zg4YLs48nWlqeH26YGCYQm41UJ@Ol3/YCnKvwIGckWcL5S8O7b1mdPdvIDcaaukpNGXIGgi2R1TsVATLso7NbE@PXZDBQ5kGW1sfaVd77wDJdgY0lyvget@i3/@D756D8SUi5atGReHZsTY9Yb9bXBVKIVWh9258Ji@UzT0QgdhrJCP9I@LJOLpRhyKmccfhN0knWOZyKfT@SMYTymihz5hydLu2k6sD7i6SPtJQE//hy7Tt5IKX00XkmhfcjH@D72mFJT7Mn4Xn08UX0@r@VLWT7O58GIHznviT5xPBHvrUfy1D5zRF@vHq3HE9HR91eT6KqmCgPNbdLk9Zvbz5yQw7hWHWjM69v9aSoKlmZsx0goT/x4pyO@jcJdYv5VTllbwVkLXcStu/WpBAq@lxh/PkxikZO36VjDDx/wCI0Tx3diuwJfKH3SVWThmPpA@Ilb4Pg4/fGxcyiMQKPcfvhA4mQ70qaFlk0PJp@sUgVNXziZZRvkaVWX0y2UZx7cW/X6vwdyBdUFmXzC99cYAGaD2OzdAacBNdka9dpUYbgkqut9UDzHx3uCp5zQH1dpqxN/EB7lhpy782TRMjmlBy6ntANKzsCgvc6JEyT2XsaH3ogrwZnbTvownIx1sv8ctOl1OIKv3HvSedlY5wyaE3xtqIfmkBnyimhsAQy84HloU94St5tm1Rbo@EYevsL6IL4qecMCECzwhrFA3YgPHyC@nkbyfLDf6eihLc12rLTJcPKSanidpgbG4Zm5bt19TBM/uBOIIluiJ1upQ0jFur6TPIbkMW8N3kkeIO6J@V6yAcn4psd3kmVItp@J3J@uQbq90/8OgIVeniCuT5b2ZPGy4rEP9MCjQF5she2hfb4VY9ciQNsNY7fHbn7aORqF/mi3ji1sO@IF/ZOIlQ2AIu1xOg/eb6SFpOKRwh5bLrbKtHlCf6G/WZjjHAksfiIlgdrF8r1HO/jpLQKg/4Eqpd@mrwq3W3td0R35CcKw08fWBmaF6V9@@RpljiDuyh/3uJI@u4XQD3erhja3NnjsF9Ft2tXOtHQy7c/jHB2zrd1WPhKbeqw6ZWijQuy@tenXkqz2oAxA/HE7Gl2evPSnTcy9@Ugfr7XHho92t/g2H0NvpAc9okiP9NPdTVD4fq7yKPeQk4cRubtRFnhOGH/yhp3mGjqwC30G0GtuvpIzYUdmnF76ayv7fbU5APpIpya8ObEVrQCm4ZlD4B7yeLtdt3WCjezQfWzH4wv25F1k8jvI7PP0ngCBdQo04Mi2UuOrMVFWg/YzqaDn2VDET1zMbZCXDZtWyup7@PTP0LmQcc6QPcF3Du2qJHoPa96Ar@uN/Dp73eVeVc/W9Psrd28/1Oz@5EYa6bfyRKTuE4ySxzRLrw9uOqFfvq2H/nGc@bJpvh17x/S8rytWjb6SxO8RwZd3GP1NIdutQuiR3uE4kkA0wzeGJHII4f5BaeNa/7SKWbld2n37XQsMqTrZTUeabYSrBDCUt3P5HZvrbKM6ndMXn6yVcePfWGH4qj9bKsBkP6G21TlO5wpk8N6OXR8dRTiynYJPsqOFaawok6WVbQtm8CpfUHjCZraZjPyEPt3XtJ5nZTA5BgPBsDqhA4D89nFWa7PKNi83xUNxjtFL951TPlbj7gnEfHSiyLgCEWh8OrKJRBz1Sbc5wW6zZd/IJnkTJUnH0QiKWj19gM6Ktvahj1/HI/TaBPqwN9NK4@OZZOTkSkfPk5F4Rz24sryKjqHYHPbU@tSF8euGQJgzmGhvzrckbfCyZ5XBPsPTOd3yy/bURT6Rg2gTrxt95QXpPVlTc3rqwmLWAv/yh4OPzMQ0mK6sMqI6BaO6u6AOaFG1X8B0jG/pDiTQURhfsu1oE@KXTZwQQUygpbC0oCrOPM6LuPEUUZeXss@kI06LHIWH@BK/cUWc9sDqt09s0TVzTn4XMFlggxPd0kiKUxA5u47@Rf5lc54qS54icmYMDjmnBM8GxoPPF9ixC9tXMsDZBhKHJxR7t1DcY06icF0PLhe2HxLq@JPeP1JmUOSFARKBsveLPZ2C5iKS/EKZq6bHs9aQFfjwCgQV@5QJnfiOYhHEOjEX5B6qj/ccBuwY4uKKcu/MUyjiEIwpiqbpKOToCor5T4EBNuM/1Bu5fK0WdF6hYXuso5e77ceMjwiSA@vI2wDWbrzorY7HBdqN8gEri7jt8lIb5ET/Eh5hsQ6bsCvMkJ02r/A8QrsGAY7cvanGGt5rgxOWkMednDsTeck6p3roYEch7zbZPFvZAqtsK@AtVnz4Jjd4QcCDIK7FsQYUZ0VFAaJtXnzYsAODyJFV@b51@eY9lvm4Jt5OD7xJD@ykB@10m6gNVFAYGBug420g18GX/7@4K21O3GjCn6NfMWbLDuzKHI43ScVrxzIIoypARBK2qWTjwiDbquVwcSxQiX970k/PjA7Mevet90O@gDRHX9M9p6Y7Kfcsckkx8wWuU0FMO232LlWczlJ0n7xWdl6kRVqUFD6Lm1JqZZzxIZNxmMr5c0fry5y9TJ1YweP832W@0u8j1fIxlZmy51n8@DdUA4Xsg0FdWdzS0uIkGv0qtx/jHO5hBdwqyepob1Y7aZRqQ0R1J4fUTSDKPcz27DSB8q6iexy2mdzZh/NcUW1J/ZrfJkPGfnphWDtsJCUlxvmOBbfmkYTwcPZeCgTDhKIJbblnuvJGVd6kwKLUnkZraE@hWQMn1rZN/BSfdf@NH23sWeJ0uTe7M7@TlK8l8/KmRVZA3Onu5XaLKdubLGbLUCYqpl4ZRRLcm22IuzuJ9hQr0MEjeooYZyjvg9xPl5PhXtxPpDsK3VO8kHucoySdFKho9f1SEyLz2fin9Na47I9pVjgK18LCnLrPDu2NzGWbRThfzMkGQmJwJubLp6dRpPy6iRVf55B8Vo7e4zJCAjE1aSgaDi6IyvImntTlGKpUFC4gr3DPMMmYLx8eZMhzgZiq1LXeRwRyUTSsyUZGY4cbtCN55SUUS/hxRQc8omVfigjZctJ64rj1RUNfLJKs3kv7nixoCkSMT9nnIVyt/mIYvy2jwafqpTgql3@qlH@opESmt6rLxR@OOai7niLpjKNypVx@Xzk2jOr0aSOvNuYHBcA6PgRAUzQx0F@RboafEfPUsGjE4IJzmvrPw9nncFg0DC8c8h7w3ZIlAlVezkPpRZn9vCKF5lbwd0/T3fHcFLTsekT3gn@Mz9J37YAda5gG7hA9hbNxtJA3jaafoyEEqO9N3U9Ho@mKN6JxZUnKA5XG4YKE8rYgsiSxX1pFC89d2F0sSaOvQrP376af2Y@0EgPNUyO43@cLQAacKAJCGpmM65yihPANRv1oDHXaQQC8LCUS0AQQa8PlIHyVBoOJ@B9p0DHnh9PBEp55@7plStT7TdlWyNzDWUS9byJgbhWulqKdGjhoOL7w3XpwbXm2oOeO5145NbsmLnoiaNii6nZ6HGVKNNwm9S6@sNo1Sm0HnnPRDVxKyFk@1cxxhmG1e8K@6Xi27wvXE06r03QIGoH3rHbg2L4pnHa12aXB@tIUBEG03UA0nZYTULHANRmrrmYk9YRbFy3bqzbo1bpwmk7QY4x1J2gDWZ2wWaJjeYFT7TYtT3S6Xsf1bQHGjJrjV5uW07JrRYSqarvCvrLbgfAbVrO5xah73bY9EJ/h8sImKq2Lps2YmM@a49nVAAwlT1USHhHYNIXfsasOHuwbm9ixvJ6pgPr2b10qRJmiZrWsS2LOyH9FKtQu1a5nt0A0ScLvXviBE3QDW1y6bo1l7dvelVO1/RNhNF2fBdb1bVMg7h@jJhgkLcqn54uu77DcnHZAY0a3Ezhuu0CNfE2CISotqlpjAbttyS0JyfV6gAo5cAOY4rphU7oHmbK0LEjBJ6lVg3QxQkhCDNJsirZ92XQu7XbVRrYLMNeObxeowRwfBQgm8F5bhLTLXKOdiC75SMpqaM01uTmFUxdW7coB5ao0aYDvKG1hsVUbSuZkyyVj55Hbqwd4L0/51FbI607iq27NphmfDLCSS9K7NOj8nD28y@TRQBNn0qs6BeWx6nYY3i0fbqPJ/RRL87iaPMEezx9MhAgqIOriH8YrYV/VQTlXePPm9vbKuqV1rn97WzC/pWaGjK/VUF5YXytVUDyOpv0hL/Mze0tpQZ0dKF/vpnS8nN5rOYg3HwqiVBqGqhouLwKw3iZSQQkI2BA9I99q7E9ECiUfMWf3ijhixvZmkT7enM7pZ/J38iLHhlQCdc7yu4VSCWtYJgORT0RMPyHhoCAqMgh/BxDdM8riPAw/PeTLaXRY8qsNqoKuw2UXtAx8yBe@Uv0ufNiqfrhdn4nFXVOerGh38NpNOxRzym9KZEK1S3HGnOXl1h7/FTQ1jIgmhQWJii@yqq9P8geyOvyLyr3CwknsSpzDgbSsG@cai7ny0fHJVnojTpe2hVvniG1D493vXO8j/zU@ygJkYBGWXySSaCOPVEulVB2alfF8Mi4MX/WPKLSKhjSmYqh@DHlYh4d86S44XZ8G41m0TlNP3fClZ7UuuvU69Zyg9vjn9z/9eGIoj/uzxY0p/3vAg4iMLF2aRa8imqZxVspKqjTvqb8IlpOK7oPWQ0EEONSNxol9mtLGnjPlHEHG15DbQGB3jggDEwTZyCFIwCwncD8/3DO0vu60TKUA@QyrBXAz7q95ht@nqRLrwEB6yRxtuNXW@AHs2Py1iccMKQVSKhaOnxYb0lxaXHC/l6trhwO8tuFrxShSzGk9furrb5CkYNBnshcG3MHnN6XbqVakeS0aGvbKzc41iYi9bSp0kBYOuUQoOtO5tmCZGFHKjdI3euyp4EDIQqgHa@GTGOtxzUMdvEfuOSvDUJA/np1SEx0cxJg@CGykFhRRcv8/GzombQ1MivygQWwB1l8exXKOc3gT@vz7gvhLaiq8egPOidJY9U6au4sdBeVEu0RX7zqCjJCwkoAynLSKcRi6SE8XicWZEdP/JQ@G/x/KZAf8D7TgJOiJtLgfjibL8BslyVClrGj1ykKJVvqLsdRnaok000m9BMxzumEeY8bUZ3hrebBEIlCts9EJPRlSLL9DAFBy7Guk7RcOfNmIH/u0cjpn2/1OnvTPJoPxU14H5NJDxQu4H02ec5n6Ezm8FOQRflmk0DURX@Wc/Txyn4EFF/VidxuxP89JGO8q3OeA6dJb3vSIrZxVE2KoaAtP1KmsTEsb/1p9YZSMMkOd@0xT0S8H@4qPQxBTKNPh6xMQ3YHwt09phpXYCOcZCN3JNzy98C6/UKM4IjZSF8jjsgjYPce8f89rZgxFypcGnHYAJeDsD1XMprtwscJwMZLQ2YdIAk3k99mNCZCovch4GqE730KRpM6D7Cqmnrcpoa8x9d3Jpwli@4Zyi0uXKGYiQKVdsBZFq8/BoEbfxncuQf4OYj3L4ncm7FdlIM8rsTXHK3fCgpX@/jyRCM04V5hd0jiUSKk/@ITEnNbRaHUYremPcR0qznVMI1ozcMS6XZP@5y8uCKArW9/Aitwfk3gT6Rc5kJ3u6@kLnqTtxk89PKl95lNiioijFHwwq6ZBIBnzJnyk@dLamL5/AQ)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Symbolic Brainfuck (102) [local](https://github.com/KelsonBall/Esolangs.Sbf)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Gol><> (107) [local](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [online](https://golfish.herokuapp.com/)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- Stones (117) [local](https://github.com/cheezgi/stones)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Boolfuck (130) [local](http://samuelhughes.com/boof/)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)

### Explanation

Extended Brainloller/Brainloller path (Extended Brainloller exits at x):

[image]

Corresponding extended brainfuck/brainfuck code:

```
~[~+{{{{${|+.++.--.@]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+.+++++++.
```

All Extended Brainloller commands have R%16 == 0 or 15, so they are noops in Mycelium.
In Piet 116 is now obtained by 12*10-4 (was 11*10+6 before).

Pip was complaining about incident tokens on line 3, so I created them on line 5 instead.
`V` label stopped working in trigger, so I changed it to `Q`.
I moved tab to the end of line 3.
`1` in `//"1` is for whirl.

Answer (score 5):

## 134. [Aheui](https://esolangs.org/wiki/aheui), 5346 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxx  h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRc
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l@O6O4/111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희

♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see a y and a x here. <
>{-<
>SET y TO 88. <
>SET x TO 32. <
>PUT x IN y. <
>X y. PPQs""o<>-}
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"1
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pRcxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._ #]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002221 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5464 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL3bcuvKkhj4vBDzB36pRelskuIFBO/UbS1eJUoUSfGq69YGQYAECQIQAF7X1omeF9vddsx42u2Odtvu0@3xxHTE@MHhiYmww46YiPGrv@K8dkzM@YMzmQXwJlFrrd3dlEgUqrKysrKysrKqEoUOb/Z///s9/JCqpsx7imYRSzQt0jXkiWgESWZOPvOyGQtHGAah0kZvPBJVyzxk9ghHiKwKchfuiaUNRVVeiAbEhwnRDa1n8CNi9XmLiKbA66JJtLGljy2iSbuzRQjJj7SBHMCcI1ntAZglGrohWjQ9SkhTVfhRp8u/Som9KlA3IN0kOVH5efSzRQRtNOLVrgmQcUJylUy@lH6FIUHIlWaYIuIRRNPUMDJJyCwvCq9AUwDKG7JWSpfPXiVxIXIGpPO6Is4I3zEtgxcsWVNt3lUNrTsWsF5WX4ScyAtJVkSTEYDmU6I7LRDEANkjhsh3bTBG0gyCWchoqBCZCLpOOgrfDwpEkQG2EEoSEVlHFpCu9E0y00eAwdRG4iaJJlFFsUtMXRRkSRZo6UScWaJqApVmkMjCkExlRSFdUYEMa5IEPyAjY3MjyiYgyHQ1hsBH0F9VYHW3LwKMKi6ZIOrAPWSChswGjix5MTV4XQcigZF1INySRyAzsuU2icibMkolZDFFtUv5p6/kVSO8ullLMpF5wgO9Y4PiNkUDGyFI8ZK@aIiAkl9JjGdqyBawANmbJlWRN0jDEEXvtuxuFQmFaViChRUJ0uY7PnbnKwU3NKOdI8jrFrNnRBrXFwxPgidk/@kIvicu1xGTL@fIl/0HDNuiCk2tGx7eS05@TUz24UGE74zrsD3jhQGsDHBFIaymWywf0IHAgAUEsjwGMRSYhIO6slEwOX7VFhvCZUN1oTVIUSUtP62ZMDYM7I5rpvJDqLSiqT3gJ1TWGKvID5XEQ9AEgga9yU/ECXBNU@020qaUw42@DI1mYpNsdABbqVCGgloB2XM4uizX1JQxhYOcpoUCCFyBrIixKJEWkXhZwSyQjqhsqg3RHCsW5hmrXWx5UBpiN0iWZAhaF4FG2gSK4wEpjYC@NNrogZQoAIaG0GhVMem3/@xfdXs9wJMWBM3oOuLaIl1NoOqPp8SCTiEosJrKK5QsgPNj6XZ2KGDCK3KXt7B4de4UQYmgpU61sdIlGhRoTGXoWn1@At1RkkTBEm0htzWmn4z4oa03ZFtyoeIjvgMNSwugZdNqB8jnLLSSIDJ7VGYCo7ElJUlAzxO3yf7o@XTo@fTxQQTivEHvwT7L9o5A4IIHNAru3F@TnFZ6Q6OBcrF4U5O7jD63@poaJgGBuIQTTRdVj3sLh9vvNjpubxD1mcd7JJ8IQUlWux43yHgGynV7j4QT4V4@fDx6lXuzRMAyRSzYW0WP4HUxoHFon5iwI15Wg/qctAJOaCNNM5@Q45gc3IhGvryOm9gRe3TAQLHUUD5ADQVNRRR1TyjIeVFLINzOamPCroq@wuFU@FB@9Ln33L7NqlMMUNOtimJfbcgaai1F749BRwNTVFMH7W2g6Ao8CI@JStyCUdtPOlSsqeYHxUJV4lR0GyLpgB5dihHtkXaPw/wB1JMOhnUPWsJtd2ixu9GfQRdAl7bMN0pZ0aZQMKUNhy/QICoWzvegiSCzXaG0XSG7RBqzXbWhCnoFsXVEkgx0ZOgL2OtAtTuiv1FHAI@EbRjAZveVDRU04ueARbCHxHW/IbIEXWoEWsKYE0FE1QM6SLTHFSxkTLuhCfYKWi6hQDgW2@5qb3qaZbDpwB3o6gX71Q6FlU9vWQkwAEnilCi82hvzPTSZVMjCC4KoW46@gpqYFmik18MOjQw4Y2jQ7DP7n1@XTccSZ3TdKAN1vd16zojIo5JxjKaAAjqV8I7ZR7qyAdpJmb8uHQAmrwp3/YQgWwT85HqHhKUhAEImzkRhbIFyA0Ge9mWhD7KL1Km2erTHotfFQ9Rm6aDgA9KqaCSGO/0hzATZVRSS8S6KALboWzwwxiKq060I2vibEV/HzJujHYi1FYkwHmzEBlk@CLL3DZwjTdV2IAVGrtAiyHaK3Q5gkNXRGITxa2l90c66shBXTQRtBtoDej7IX9@ydPMQhgvZ6o87QZAUtmHMi1ZFRWFhLWMuW5od7ihaB9SzCf2TXZbACuOOPHtVIRq3asOByUzADpNMcgID@PMYpM7jlkxQnDQ@i8AbSS6qwCkK@9cFgBQoCIzySCZVyQVQKvW5KnhcQdqVgtDpXH7iwo7r8kIAc634ktVGqIVIm9oHaPBlDNBcEmgrR/dT1c/vHPFWYwA179zu4ECTVc8X98ePH92H7lPQ8B8/foLQMYY@YcgHoU80FKAhhAtiiObw0xCm3tMcGPfofrlfYp55H7HZZjg6LWTdw98fHkYe/fw951zDePWCqgPNBtABvAAet/fkBINer@t0ChUNdiS79jWbs10qDTVR7THiTNcMi5QrufxTNd04P3GxY9NgFbnDqjC@Po2gB8NcxrUjP0xKltkhWNM064Q2GMZT6AIAOZM1xtLG0Odh/iGPZKtIZz@KioK9brRlahbKXSOoyqLFOKPRWtZxIrRuG6gHhS9uzokkQxutNJzJiEJfI679iAtt@a35KA77TmoUU8fObHQjPoHxI5xJBgWmJwgkoNm3q0gHMImAOLsMwmSO6fl8CElnm6tIBzJFUeKMM2h0lpFfuNALxq@mmxvjyCbGXenvZ6K82TE/dgqNY4ldrSMqs3g0ICpS0JotgqgW4lHGvpBA9z2IHXmZ2WJXBsaCPh6YSa8SeIOxKWzAWFWCqQkpySZdTthsTmbVER4Yl91RI9ujkGudEl6bjLvtXNcmFiq0IAhDDdXiOvQERl1sCwVM09/mlGSzT3@2QN9Q9DaF5jZHHYn@7AA4dGwnEH2cyCNLLnAaiOabpsGkf0rB6ChAkQGrZJVna/SC48EuerZHti1iOqI0hqkh25FVDH8DLJBKUkip05HfAwW@IOnL6w4wY9zZxTYQrv4b44dsMd4aG5Yidp3rf/@DLjTA2@bp83OY0gjDVeAJ@IZNFZDebS0nK97Qn90tS2EGY0XmKRto6FsoBR6nnbyyCuxGjaqXBAJ93oDGnS8bF4QTf2AY/Yqc2ZQbojLuisvr7kIoi7dNLDu3Ko9ojeCK9iIdL9/J/spAtPPjtN1QNL5LsdjLKbK4bm27XcQZ34PKsRsaCTThd9C5tOPIev0EDBZrbP/iksm32lXW8fu1/upAhmJ8hxNhssl35He4iETE35Nru7uggRGQFH5oB58wuLuqdmUMudcDw8q5vgcGVjRMdHReENkpvbyrYtSxqdtNgaGv4DMU@/c9kOX67irwHiBUU6E/v0TsqCAI0DeQVFyyDGywSH7FVIXvzNEI6/9y@cEC6TgK6uVE8PlCERxSV3Pc9eKorr@fH20Amj@V2p3bXkelCARNkkTxW30Wxh15xCuBcHcj@K4KXhqt69AO0AE/4cGcVXgTBMRy2CxOoFnoz9eEFocSYazwxjr0FZFdk7NcynhvNrzOo8uCpsiOZC5v3tOFr@cRazS4Uk5/1lnx7i1/u2C64zAdWIV2d2hNsHBG@o4cfYd6sieDON3eEIyg9h7vBG2K33d7b1@biPbv7iFrsZOq71A/AYVKBkwH32bvCt8SV1zapD@7uTjcSZUlKDvjD8mVphl9UTVJOBhCA0el6/EwYCuKPTttFCvvy7QpK5pJ6vT3a7wAk9807d/d0rzJNplXA0Lf7mOr8O5sO4miwxtJ0993GpdXepoST/ZYHn7elYCxIaGWd67fq@FWGorjvqmhVuaOpnLO9V3VPoT/bwkHXWk1cAFiI/gVK2qXOnMmru9XEGYEuKq4u3KFUJLmDLL2PO29BjCE/pSfL69/i9HjPe4uRw99To1lsOYwQyoJAcuwDei/TWnRr5fW/T4d9QZt4luV2GjcoSKCxqa/b5qUhEPcL8zBhULfr7EkZSyOxZ0apNIZiCA2X9Md309UyKnGvrOywQLzcBN2BbVwpoLfRTWO53j3VYXDKzJ08m9aMztVjQ4Wto5T5yoEqhh4m7GnjvWtxt3gXW2s1r7Oub6@7Nlad4tITPmlGin5bZtpyww3RfrdrUAO0b0AJrzaCGwI9Tva30FKF4Hs3y3ENGaNeSDjepTxVbyHZLVSCfYr2CPQqvLQDOCi1vcpnvB7M3UKnErBXEwVrTn@vsftXYq0o2nKL2kd0KddGc00MD7RG@FbrfTG9nEWrcl6TcLE9Y2O9N5qhD3WONNG4B5Okd9t6CpUyaKDw/e08ptVvq@MWhtrft@aE8KITZd8TENYht@jt4admwsmg4mvErxcD2OXga8hSwUj32Mf6Uujly6p4jKsvfC6dqfYe6V/9DlwSu4GTKEvjkR6@xWLn@8Oxuby8i7QTMPvjuQgSxdF38mny9DhVfzdWuTdMIksTRVN1uKNnohzFUXkwRq1Y99Tssu11p3MLY74nlj4pmStFxxwO1Mw5K3g7qWHQ3uHQYBs31Aj9jRQU4fi3FxedxvLcwHaczz6KrZdnVzAdc1v9uogu3N9@Rs2n9rX@mpf7Bu0Z6zu3usbIJGW7VH1tUoA/X3eHOL@raOQdKtEAs9kY7bXNzf5rGiK8j18RtVoK0pN2734mkcPqi5k/UV453wHEpzLN9fpYASn7KJD@Xu9qC@OYaAyNUvTxQC9ewvq7M9Qf57Vlq/pdxyRIE42HLcTc@XbtVdUBUOkG8DLDUGyh9vS4xHM9y3NCBIK5/HwPp/Xy9iZcMrYUwFsCUW9a3DL3XbcMQlM5C0KK0vk/p7sf5kdhg65F3JCXIcu8vhoY6Wbv/mZTt1ianbW@33@8WTfHQi4990P6iEJuSmoqIAFvxOU34KTZHqx6VxXnaj8iO7yY3hZ0yPblQAm1uit0@fVriKSJgxBdLlBM@wNcdvrooErzP/tr7uOExPoHJOMZBMstp6KjnfaSOxr0092uU7paV3n0QkKcUz7uISKpQeyaWJOZQt0LPVdgnl/s9BIOq4Qjmsg3FRR02xQYTcqjn7ooGPZjWZT09VEWyadgle5lpUSNGU8UslU7lp9MwizZFUQqavFanMMQgimWgYKeddPiqQr4gpfFwmjGl7RtCHd9UNK/ttf2w4gkCijCGF4WTz1/9ookeCoRb0uBEEbA9VLJAvR0BwQDzIZtMwYjSfoUaId7yVCn6eeKSCJgaVfBhZj@2Zk03USyBM3@i/ibu@RLHn207Wz1n3o8eTXZMSK//0PWO8Xh2@uXwUSnOnykyXI0QvK1WZyCJLXqW7i2p@5nGqhpxx1DFsJleP26sEwba6ln8WIOtlRuROn1M@Cbl@qqETRe001oX/ArZeitjvNyb5nbI/UgbpFYujkCYMfDyHbLY/6K6HPAGbZn5GfSR9lJSAQLhaCO5shCrqpjE4yy/2ZyOYWGpsTO2O6oDwJB8ORE1qd/aeT41MaMsSuhl5j9z8@zMKhwMMskX9kzSVzHh5mvwqFb4B7mgG5fmCxA@XLuS/7wdPQzz@bMHV2uV7cR/aWIvTy/S/VYjVfb6QbzTpw88Wu7F5BM0b8WlOgLOgKL0D3Uag7HrDFkEXz29pjpUFWdwDu8ZB9nhyjw67Xu0pYgTqsdgVc@3ZwBQKj6Wbub2Tfld8UN9LfAjiaSZKJo0VJlQqSIzNuc1OD@peyhe2C3X0MOnvJEdwl3qEKKY9c5AS4FAAufSePyNta2i34iUZAM36bUV/HsQsF8GoN8RYAmbQqC@trp9uV21n5l7@HGuswrv1da0xxfLXGCPG1GgPgOhvNUUgXS81afjsTiNPa9xrsFANd5yXat2wvTlu6NMdjcKmZYODp205AvLLWrSaZyKbcUUQqbxKODGBP0@5I95VM1C4EFVmQpBUTNHm3C6qpM7dQs4FKD1JPAtudIKAS1x4wK7gaaP3ExSCsefLWcww01xSmncJPduZ9Ckcxm8wOT9cHkf3tP/tXtnfrgwXhP3TCEoT/qR3@kUUGvfXQs2lcsQbZ0ipWiQnDpV3xET/bqBOOWDgiyupYJPIIODihDEFwm9h1fdd4PPct4Cc0AjATVS9qW1qeaDx60L/qkGXRwMB5Y5DuRoszaAdQ1tTd6nmM3sYwQLDxWDzKsUBkYLJEGJBthAHdRuj1HoKsMRNZP/mpI5Dj42PiMgVeEU/iRzYj2X3@x4jrpxWh@wDL2LbIPYE8kGWdA9JOnWyefd7HeTErdjk35yaPR2Bm2O0CI5WHBgDEi9Gqww8XDIWawypodFWcWVSdz5c2Fhg4KnWbEW2f8yWiACCycaNT7GvZXW9zovPHhjQHN5vB1UawOoIdunaJzv2P5MF6UB8d32gCAvOXOwRJhfAf7XCYXklP@q2rrue1oy3WhnyuqxpufBeAWuIJs@EIy8W9Gz3F5aACerFf/AwooSdAzxJEeaDpZjqbL15UqvU3rqYU0v0azE3cp8e@h0DQf/@4CrhfSf2SqZkCW7/KFJas3KRqvYKEEOtlpNdk7irtNaXvlN6295jflk0T3hTEhb4XMZ2oBQp0pfUt9nUquwGYtffA3pTq8X55uX88Pn1Q994U//MuL/y94AEKF4QeTOqD7yY7dE5xuXPewEekzODSCSvsWj9jsnIxs@/X0e87i64euFp7jC736NFbNHzKdsUJq44VhQm@s3sPdQ@ydlHUXdImbEkv6JolqRySui5QYN6sAm5SQ5y6vH02zPGaWzGpYk9PqTc8r8LMxJAFG9qkCtqexFLXbZjGFK31zAdmU7hyQyd4czqZAVWx2lHsynT9gjeW7nyrlLo4kgONJT2oONYeoKDI0LOxD3VT5M4Rf3I/IysftK85hwZNXZEtD3plzoI4SYTaeLxYAe5YEdGp8zj16HiQkqWjp4/6ilbHwK@qppP1xDwnLkM1mJuR3BiQgxiI5GI8AjiJXmoijhIiKWsByAx8dC@JuIdSPE4dgqNuDEoP9sVZV@7BSOPx@kEl/Yrj1l6mvNcHE2o36GGbVWe4VbrJmF/kGbvBMf6eD8pqV5x58CmIw0fkDsS7p@2J2@t6IwPUPdfx1e2@9tNdKgvecnrt2sf1lUJIpVaKYLvvpFLBvsmgjyDMK6DEumWUIAhjqEca8TrxjKmjs0mChN56Hjyq37QMLwmc4ng2JSrx@eiMBC40IUhoTomGZAUX@zz4eJCHPYF2xlhT7eJlIevkngsGHyFMC/GSfVxTyIK5gbNxLwMGJ2Q5pGhhAIa/Q6RoCnMvpMi@7tNiGVwQMABqZzLtyL0@7YDAC1prcvoDWWuDdQ@0uZpKHTqtsa0OUwTE4niHxgC0O9Tc0uIE/jqOXsA1VGIAlYWppgwK5fOlqKrQXz0gMyPonYQfg5AZXv/y2VT/@rEnWsKeTeK54zkGhG4/DpV3f1E0sGf22SM6rz16gXH/pwcc@CVn6J@z/4ANskdfPPvKyZwFY8x76tnvn3C@yIHPt68eePZVNEd@@AGnwy/7YO08BV1B1wyAAvuK9wjkGayjk331aJ8/9ux3T8IHNAfc@nzeL5Dh1yYb/LLPv7D7P4A14YcYw@6dnn3Ti90hFAxyL0Af9pB91g8y88XjIi76ZCkWvy/7fEhDcP8JCfg1@1D30XHloc7SmfeRY@SyvdFSjWzbKquWePOkrM1AJ/pwpdFj1APY3iJ4WgJvPg21I22XffT73@9xcZhEfYpHPNqncOTjwR7Z@@xiD1yG68tDbuK@56Vw8PmxOqxWb7wPHpBI91624uKiLvIjIQcss8cehH5OsOxPP/0E1ie5Pw2eBh@99wH3471ndppIHPjjyQP/ZzdnT6JhQsZxXk847GXJQ508JHj@wBcNf1aPZFnWzW4Xvlofn80DS@wEpeQDfDxc1e2ORdz1H9E3/9Onj/BH/@GzusXfjzTGiaYgbz8fvcTzPGP2Tmff/XmCbyVDgy2W48IP6gd8Tjr@8fMHqLPoo5/Dw890IkNciaRL0z4DMCH9PY6LEW0Phr6ZSDpkNgvgh9kT9haQxO3N6d8ThjmuwTd4gv8d/KtZ@Nca4l9NqAnM3q9PTnzf@ZmtQsHg0zLE7P10/NPJ3@HD7MEUZO/09PHlxRe4D/545Ds6wi/@Q/ddBo/oxw5B8Y@@gO/4/vg4eHo6Ow08nt4ze1@YvdkLsxd2gaw9HDB7J7PjGqXxPnfqUPvszKpLED4OPN5XS2A5N/zh48BeuJDO@sP1ZmaPg7vY@hYTI3hby6dzlSZAV0v5dD1/Vmzlm1WINx@fTj9/9gWhDT4HTx@BktmvfKe@E8uyyN3TQZB89fO0I2TfMnu501mTDRwDsSUnpkaLCTzA3YMXCvuZ2bvfu/d8Cn8Kh5TQJMQNueGVVln/VyoQL89CA80I9UN9rgsiMQuJzdA8NJ@FRlqF60JQhL/QCIJySJqFeiE1pHLcFp73/0cV7aqiASoNslmzkIVYQxJce5XKFSCToOAB/MmhUGgGBM5CE/gPKZ8r8UqUpULK/fgUopX2hh4emHvi@kmEzh/k3MGQOxh3u@XHWFx//vISjj/fU9Mglnq8F2ey9egifvfTw30qlXI/Hu2x5sMDa@tDVzjqOkKQl5enp1y6kX56YnGlZHa87/vsC3yGz8mp79i5fNrrniJrg8cfHxi3Z9put/Hbnk6mdogG7Lj2KnHzhgbgM3kn73ZgtlsYPJ772OOXF6/X@@HBfeS2a@LxEBEMXo@Le5iFJRJ2eaklnIJhhIugsRKPeU9P4zG4jye9AU@IJttZHly6rj@4gnRmHaQOIycnacPg5xQoCiPZg4s3nh5c9@HHk5NUjEbHAqk40YxAKuJ1eb0/csfHThlhL0S73DOXZrjJl5fNP8@Xl2MP/Xjxz@vFSOf31OuBZG8M7mZfPLNjz7EH4yAKc315OcUghfsCoXuP99H78mLHwa/He2zjPPUC73D54O/xXzOJqRP33sseWiAqica8ns5c9EbjnqQv5fydfIQKeFwRdwTq5XLz7vv7zweRg0T0/tPjweOB5/ggePBw@ril373uPQKyvJS9E24P@cbsBY9qLi7scqMsHuE@gKaIQUXrkUjqaFsY3E@eg9efJJfyHfg@3x@kUnbZBwc/f4RuA@igMBd89kB@iYccnx6vhGqN0nsK3y/EYTKEX76AnNlpYNB4nJX@h4dZiPZHLznqnOx/2eNfjih@8uJyH23JK8XvcR/RrSDXF9c@b9xzj64X1/6XzgtafgeclxoYsejR0UHUDieSEOYOvPbqZiwEd8swpIgmL9Cee7SH4uQGnnuhVicdsSerYO1tMckXi8XYMPzOfhXPh2fMEW6Z2PszroDL7kAkmaL49ohpphiYXHSg5ackEYIRVFF4g2iS9NGOh1kS6YgiGKqiouBaH04iwJZWulOYuH5k9kDRgMFiivAZVXlxLIrT8Xgqrj5Z2TzkB8QzgEkwfn73mz/7h/D9a/j@sX3943@fiuHv737zv/xvv/2Lv4LI/wLf/wzf//S73/zLP7C/9P6/wvf/3oj7r853A87@MoDrn/zuN3/yb3/3m3/65/D9N873z19/f/un/9H@/3@cPwz@1W//9L/ij3PzD/@Y@Zv/8Jf4/yf/4W/@81/i///@v/7Nf/gXf/NP/h0N/Cs78P/@m39v/zJQ@p/90W//5T@GSv0phv8RhOHfif5DCBJfwP74NtLJz/shMNzIw8/ryD8kP7McDBOEXUUC1n/98wP64nE25BLnz2yIg2gb8o9@95t//m8hdgvyHy@zfyYQ9xrSEaBlQX8IkH@xRacD@YdMgjSr8FMrnp03Nq6NfDp7zsRJplLOvbrEHKAYKeULjdVtwk5dZo2tUNzmS6XXt87lVhsTgUeBFAlPbLXNw7QZzzoJkmPm9EsAfur5BqQ1KiSZpJF4P8P7SJjeV5t4XyyTOb29wWu1em26XNrxaeCFwV7zkcQSfn8wGIQfvPrph16D@z8uQbj37Zk95grXdVOcvc0uYw4IGWIKNxahs01Vuq/bwefux/r7kXDBKAwacq8Ps8mptgIwTROG2dWw@2YQbjPn0LlH@KQpnnJg4YRClkiICaIqCIdTyVgyFQkn/clUMhrj4rGYnwv7uUQykQr5YSqR5OLJWIrzJ6OpSDQaTfkJF46lEjDxVLuyxLJgWXIuF6EBWRXw0apjfEZNC/ZPmb2uKMFs/gOZebreD3vdZQQZJ4krknwIERfLujgG910OZieucASwk0iIcMTFuBZEIHuhbDISAiO2gzeZZCIdj7hcTzQFPtmQy9XFm0QoWcgkXC4Rb2LJUCiRcbkkvCkUsqFCweWq2Df4cbnmy5tQCArq410@HkIPV5eMN9m0DTfAm3ASi3K5hnaKfTNa3iQATMWbSAQREJfreYUOkRt2UUmay7JvQqFM1uUa27VIwp/L1aD4IvCXhExpOylKK5ihSSG8dbmy9k2UojtbYsCbPN4knZuCnYKAgE6Bu47CC0OXqwfBngE63QXTa4GKEUg9hNDbS7V4l0uAG2HOq5BP6lviIj1P9zLwyWaeerNeb3YmYIrcGPe2PvmCkzJ4nYIfmjJsjGe7U0bzcW@ZNKs4HwNT1M787WeBKc/vpigbKZV5pVtp4Iem9HrLhF5l9aEpOz@YImkOmD1R1eD6JIHt4lojoCn0qsxmriOQaQZ7F5l7vF@oge4hprwQofd7Qv4xWKWxT@OkK55wHR7A1fXJFYHgzENCbrAzXO4Hl8t7n3r85ErEXIcwHw@4f@A@waQ35Tp0JRIu4j1yhaFrxlyuOAmD0N/B0Cz2Am7yyXVkiNbYUEn46AUpWJyEjigl5NmDV96Pvx3vFwesc/SCC35A5rNn4fP54ev9hBSDeQ0zBu/hHAwa79ELyx6j4uBwMskyzClmOrHXCAEQJHaZZOuWlXIgMIcIBgl8YUaO6fqJzQiPK@UhYDxIMvw@uKhtZS/ceNzuRNjt9rqPAMlH4trQqN4jSiyxmepZcsYFvADOpGAq4FTfkwqAoUoCKSD9DUnG8NC0eANX8miJh8QVT7kwGg/cSi0L@@wPcP7Dg07s@PR/YGzDKc4xey9MF5/JiqbIUeoIZ9lg0R@fOnkuyTzR851vkHzE7LuRaHdka46zR3/3cbzdC0S0qLa3v78PU//GqSviqgSfjllnin7K0rn5w@lR9CSLCwwwHAcfno4/@n7pJ4iZg6eflwsMp7iQ8uYTjTKGiD4nXTyzy55wJWPI1x4x9wDNke9v84GSmRNAyhyhTe7a02vCbCYoc1zIIQ92RY9/vUdnZKT6ZekDMFbpNsXhFS5Ke/jDOn1u9v6ReH9dlpUvyUjglK7qoYgSaOmXeurHxI/JH6@alWal8Dl0mDxMPjw4zenn3JybNtXTZxjD5Fqe2TN/9mox7tfqxdHeoe6ORN0RQh5O9ux6cwnv3mk4ETT5@d6j4zvniSZQVuGeGuhhjuxJ7e3PdOtmMqKrLVBU8h90ez05/A@ufvp5n2XdbkK4/dP7X87KJ7rgBCTEfx04tv@P4YdkKzaFrnjM5UWXRPPHpx@f9ghY6cQVjmFH8rHEtsM3Zw2e2YH644EKf@KBSf9Ekd6qB8enEGVChHMvIoToPWBZ9joMtkMqFU/G95jfs@zXtvMgdbW@LYmiYY5Huxa404Z8xePiv7pa5IbA1XghGnBdnsG1NDIIWhm4g4NmxmacY3lsRNGj67bj5iaLTkQYyzAYkunZh0RC7eTBeahFnUHIAR4ciL6SXuYL8wFwjQWL@h/BzxHDfEBHGLz1LOH85AfT8qKTQMjLfPjg6FnTCprWEyLHTE5kgDtiXhhkD9/tmgT3Huiev@1gyaNbiabbTx4oc2JnMulAYhtM1DcSy90g@IBINhVQmwNCS6SUY@Xs4j/YYJ2xhKQUiqU85CEnRKJ7WE5ul9HBI2Jo9T5KXqdwEoIoxILglFMUHAEBHUR6KG7vCL04BQ@F9BEO0yW6FwZQYD/6KSV@IjkZ7/H2EbIjeklQNBMQ26V77BqQgyenWKcOy@ELKwEsxNrRoYGOcUZP8Duth8/i3z96yZelr5gHU8kxCa@d2Rxc0Bj26Y40ozDq2oJDz95x2EyxcY9@aNoj2@fIs4JzYtaMemEOLP/oyG4q/Yi59AjeL7hXcvTr0Q8/CD/q96PHI@/oxMKrzzeCkWrokW2QA@tkdALiod/Lj0cW6Aj58WTkvfTgPQyCMKi/MJLNbNPr1A1qrp4ALbifanr9i3s18Gv10V@4V31A8th/cHey8PMnIf8MvvIJ51f8zyecUw8o0zpZ@NQj/hi@uG2z5c8Fo7aPP9qKwixDj3KyuOcfT4AfCmT0@QpQGaDTvFd8vkcvFK5A4tuMR8oPP/A@5XR2pAQCXoT6MfKpcG9B4NF3gveHHv549mlxP4b8hx64nkAxiheIh3wOr19WtAN9R8Bju03XpNs0zpC8GZA3Ojk5uPt0cHdw8vHj4n4WGD36bfYfhtbSgMTPkPijDX85z8Gdl7xiCV0b8rh@JR/@KnhgEpdfBvvp4M6vb@S0KTy4gxQdhk6H6hfUl/TQueWWIEqY4@Nln9FDT/mgk1t6Np5JzwO1uujtCnnTpiDLDrjtpqzLMDnk8RQ7P1E1NcBTCExzDsHExIfZp0/MsmjHAQlKRuXSwdk0TDLpGWgGLlTRA1XtZzi@pV93qeGlzl3N@OrFuzyB2WUkvtFdqWqiHc40hHsEQTXwJfRyZGss2@0MlA3VHgBDtQfCBVCLIJMcPeFAnjiJ0FrLBoJcqCck@0EFPCTGRP0E6m3d80GF2GRAZ95BhuwfnFDdBPIkQ4jIx7Q8CEBXYT5AJZAGrIP8SE5BkZEffiDO7fEJzGkTOBYgGMINfBwCvaEUCv8OSgEHUjkAGUV9SAsB2j5gCjpLbhUU/bsV5Pg6eyCDb@C3XZ6D1OXZM1ZN29Mf@ea1ycC2@PBh4DuJOgTBP7XUIT@kvfx@zxnuD8FYuao2G/naVboOvzDXSK7P2Txcncj45hw2Hc9X68gqdQ0U@Bon3l4IYMKA3QgipXXxvNUuuWiWSDhczvnx0Vtg/Z69XAQD6uEKk2jSA43MoGb02Kk8lNntE5nxbEzqhUjPfw4sD8pEcujgrKyfP1g/fmDiAg8M5s7zgltH9Y5E03SOlwssT@ylpxLTJzFG@EAB9ELnODrq4LHco6YeEbhG66d@Nobck@kxrH0bwVZ@enKYZWen/YPBY@S6vMWjRDOpZCh0SEJ@DHDLQHgZiCwD0WUgtgzEl4HEMpBcBlJOgFti5mzMMC@MROLrYGIdTK6DqVUwGloH1xii4XUwsg5G18HYOrguLboqLZ6keMnekpu064oGpnHR5DINH15SLRoZAzTc68goEBp@AwnZo28iobzkdmQiFXIKKrIVBAqH4@t70D5L2BOPTZXfpsNvl2zfOZEwVjH2PIkKbN4wQCvlZ3huJgid95CgPzXDgNolgiLyYAyIFlgpJwWQf9F7aD9nZMwP1z7ViOGEW91DdjxXDvJw9AhYW3x2JId3JdvYwjux2U@JkRVjNhzSHSJtKg@3RlobY3QrbhPrR1SwyNF3IMI2BLbBtgf7ssyGMd5ZZOTrRW4h3FnkG6JsvLFduZA3Hor8ZJmVjv8U28myPNtOEWlrgxngnPdNZeBVg@IDZydfuEPX737z5/8H@d1v/uSvyG//4q/@v//0P2P4P@LP/wk2CwmvAP74T/DnX@PPv8Cfv8CfP93IROEjh67f/vlfwu3/9O/Ib//hn9hJ//zfuvzRFSJIwah1zj/7R/jzj/Hn/3L5YyvAP/sjGxCzuPwvzJZp5QGoP/4vhEBpiGWF7M//mhCXDwwMjyN593Yff9x4PMVGsGLDPQ09vk63f4W@gWwPeX0uwOvcces7HzaAdwO5weMB1uu@B@aM7RaJWlrghT4@guBEaSbaPwKaMJoZ7IG8Tbtg9DjrC26o/f9IDonbhzAQTZ@zO7F1uFN/p96udSrC@lwsUIdnQjqoMOxdUQLTWwbkm84E5mYQpy10RsrZMuLwt4wH5C8HENdSsmTLw3kZp6xlbpj0EOecYfhfT3VRaHEYsp9To@d9M443PbdR4Ja6edVsUMrrGJgyrp9c2cxKI8SRDk0C2Vb8RsbiDeWC/zW6dcs53SZfKbzqMPjpgIk53NRIq4JOiMv1DVjktAPvRYsrsg1v0@sA3IcOI49bz8HsAnbd3Ny4mI24EMqQ0fVQDBuVslXGKonbTgpvJIU3koBmGyfVNbFw@BUNdOBAvbj9zJedbUNFbWdbCxf2nGU7IBkwF7SXFP2SMjb7J29RU428rezeIt9AyT2eOP3kQaU655S4vG8yAM7tPCev23I36tAbmLcNtTsncnsrZqu13se0lWejU1DuMa@5tGo5LrWr5bYL/Apq7tH3nQWFQ3/HggLfWVA89u2CXjcr5t1C/z5/v612lmpipeHXyOyOv7c1QOHQ@Ocgemt1hBQbNOjxwpQn7Ux5OlONeHYcKA3x7PKsja1TpI2NEzhwElPWLNFeHvisazDl0NAK3ngLxa5XxjgvfeipmiGam8@3yfazAqobn7AUtJ4Ko5ofz/yQnSPSccvZfpB/e1xZjWyOFZq1X2yBqG1GoeX59CSrsvX0BManInnXDMTboIAO3G4G34gBoY38npVpW9E9Gp5dZHm/jZPau3a2hiwMPRXdSXRDIWkCEzpBVGDyRfq8MMR3u1CWYBXp02ZokXYsjxeZ2NdGWk9UNXy4FHO/Ql9c40aCeF2ntPgJ7yfCBkXOJNoj@Hmvk/XyF2cll2EP713lD28j2GKGnxiveYycNXYU9/RucXa2ZXn1X05vfZPe@tfplWTDtF7TTCNxtQevv6zoiGeNAQDXZES@TYbfeZ78DTlbpKyi8aB2O8N3k9gVTQGGP6Q0DaBpBzwogXz4V3cm3K0Ib73H/6834DJ7/nubjxqz9Tnom1EebT86RTPpUR6qIHoAvOhF3fO2uJVo576zLGeiQ2d4fuKiikvF5wCgY@q6qJqrrd4l4m/IPPrCvJF76iBzYifuoMmY@Mkw/H4T5Z66osLPxa7HgfRv4F3WuCbyXaqvvq/iqOio0tPs0/k9IT@3ZYrR57Uo0OE7IsP7J17v@2Jlg8gr6aGbcZTC4vv8owt3r1UzLoKe2HsgmgEadI8e1ECPx9Dn@tx@xlOxXwrk6FF7/LFbsoyPvn6TIcAH@5UvnH9drPdr6rPmWVXpO0aEFWxwu8r4GNcSIz5I9bYNfxmLvl1TusqwynSybOUt6@S9Fpe/1uIbUrGUSdsq@T6R/JbQfbfMbYiajWytwrK/bAh5gznLK4ogeDYx2jFfbTFNfaMTMA5bTFPfGVWedijUVU6q6Sw8e/nEti@8jAzBIlwncG3BFRHCHPTJFqhl3dCuXS550ZQRr29YLU7MvYC26AYXvZv7iBtQzDKMC7kvqzKFd8sU3pQpbJW56gHbRW4AMcJWkU4rYPN8rQkUUbLe0c6YhDN3uHxNbcNH1XgD916/uGX3oewn7on7EBSyW3Qf5j2glN1d92GOBkz3YZ0Ghu7DSwis@5b7Z/fhslsggAG3NPAZ4x0VjveC@zDr8b4w9FVwy3KD7sNVmwLMJ/uWcuTFXl7tOLv@2mpVVRT9tlHpJygxJlw0rNb9o59@Q/BPQZ3TjyDx4wkJH1BgnIBsDRobI4ZdDgwbQfquKc@u4eNwuTTlrG@s11Ag3XeysaiCUjKm@si9595WRjZhmEoXH@EKBKLePNxNEeHezMy@RY5TOkgobeTt8in3gtQe6Hpo@j0Aby7iKOv8y/baRmE34PfRiZnfo/MNOcviKEXoDODdQRYy9Sf3VyqFbf3qJB279Tdb6O0aATZiYAlitxJFu6HTwYZD25QWpmv6tpDQVNztkzfz4MfplCi9r7JRreD0zHeSabRTM1QMm53f@7XqbORD0rZUECbehx7tXrYaF6guxqS1rtuwVO3OByRs6JwufQheRLHNOUEKZ6sbPx0r3huGlnntIqnm2laTkDmITxWNecsufb0vg88a/bLp6zInmOBAIyLYyLkqxdav2i@w3zXbfl8a1EsmvCpgl2G9eyh9a15/dZR9RbmyLvZtA2Kin@S8O42jVQlrlsPsYMMy/5qsvTHx8WUctpFvF7rC/sraX7JtNSf4Bt9ezy1sXGglGJPtyCEuzA7D7zPqrUWiTIJLoyWIJTl47IqvKF1X7eu02hXf1cSYgmM0XH5xAxvbDbzZeIiPVsB4xXK7l@PLy@g@xapv45r6xs6FveugoZfY6lyojUhQ99R/beWiBRGVp1quUi7dwqCbSCS8b7cisNdC3vU4znx1m2A1bQn78RAQ@kpV9J3oa4b18UF1vXUpoxFgDPB038YWP6ePex1dtqHPX/VdyGfDbnDUwTVcdwN@SyuhqcPjkC07fLWPg/Uc8A6SpXkL/PbT2RruGqF04IbO0xMdvp6e0Dnn6ckZxbBpVttIv99zXjgU3ngv6t62N9M776TGBYDxyH4rp7MA5zxDb/uh7OEbcFdvtF7lGquWvHR2wPUh3KJaeUZ4IpzXfnHuMsZ@vy1IqiccxSlsOIYPadq5EBoXPqlrpVPOR9vQwQMiTV1TnRfgDu2XJNPjKs3l0isle6xOeeoGYpdCny3doMh2yFrui9F3WtIDeO0XiPKqvYS85I2fiL0g3fEJp2DKMZR1@4yoleuH6aWZKMHURwt43FHEEb5XEmR3x2rylQyt0i/IvR4IEuuccWw7uDTwVZMBTQpk128Jb9G3gzpn6zk@YfRcS2cdGNjp2Tq8wiThOFhTKT9wdv0FxqKbDMEDKkLUSYtCwTcBl4QdTPo38n70zL3bV2758SK@j54nbFn7uTTZwPOMJ7y6wWfncbWNpWln05LqgY2dy@U5LIxzbs4J3acMoo@a7nHtuZan02DQdpvgFWF5rIMHDxQ5ZD6oVPGgBxgRbN8aMHBVNNro9pp35ZKqkl@RSJi@mg3Ko1YqLRZw2Dt7W9ghDbIisbZ3n6NgXL/qun6Fm4nMhz3UhbasYf6lKGOYnrK3lmXy0UFnb6hgV7a7wPImtnETganGhx0Ff/S4fIDF5/K6tjABvLP78cHWvG@zglL0/p5tdOPtgpZOpxsjzqidpXvpfrp2C/eZUMnXHkTzLJs/V7rpXLEzP9MSjYkUDjVurzOdiK@a6M50@XyUPdfzjBy9HfnuIrPUeXQRy0ayaSF0I52VpGgieyPdmGJaEVPsZDC87oo1vcMZpnxZvirXFmyhed3qXQ@ku3Z7kFDrjF67y/SuZ@J1sq1OWs1U0bwWW9myNSwPrDE3ryTa8eZUNTOtRqZ/MS9Oh7NiXLuVY9lrMdGS9POpMI/pwnmTuZs0@vH6@XyY4kbdeTprdm8TPh97m830kudC9066qGcvuz0j1okN6yk@MhldSPq8f3muPpcG2fpE8OmDQjE@YdRqcTIVo@1hRzlX72qtVieXqU6HnHmndwfR9tXY6iSNeCQyTov9QTRWHFtGspRJXyasXLrYKig3Letu3kpWGevcaiSaF0JK8U0qlhAZ55qsGWrNLuTL@jR@Hm5o5@qFUhxUh2fjs6qij4e5qFxpjKJG76bQ0cLh8@v65Py2xBjRi/ZtsjYIJ3PCTGAvY5o2ijRS5ZJxNRtnnitiOyvUM2InHsrEbvLc4KoyFyqTUq3Wrurt5ihhXnLKXSE0YCo3Qj2dGRZKoyTXKM@LybNifZzNFmeTTljqaelxtx25uolPS2Wx2L5mI@f82LryydmKwg4uLsx5q3lZvCmbd9Ctry7kqDSfZVoZQ3rOZc2rWoktG8N@PTpQu3orIWc14aJajFrFYfp82r5LFTNDUap2htqw0VbaY0vODdgCM88Or5sdcVqQF1M@Hy21rtlBviZYiXQvUmcHktQZKhVz0TsrLXr1cafXTVXOQjnx@bKbacVqeZ27KpjRsjpnbhsZSV7UriVuWE2dF@86@bR8pcayVVGvnp1PZuHwrSxVp7EFN7sZFKLyTIiGSpXMzZXv@iJc85V8mUxVi1R6TDhXOGv3Ypc@rSAu2JLEPyeyPmM8js5yY3yTaKmpKsYopoSShYavnzCNdurqatoxize1bFtQFsm7q@EwfldjbiZFUzPCyYtCOsVWhyHjjB@Ui3cJWS1Ep5kzJZ8qthfNpJUvjZXkeamXu6gZucZIuEnle/X5fNhLXojV0jDNiMlcrTbo9Fqd2W3drM5DV1Fh0PHlz/Ll5x7041a9EL5oZuK9cS3Susypk2qj4FtoN@2Sni0PuXw1OY43EpERM5ldJNN1S5X13NlVKn49lkv5dK7XzHKaKN48C5fckK835qGkmTCuCzfXuumzGh0t2ulnIvPrq1u2dWeasXOZuZu148X00BAuuzPrwkw01LBWuQ5x11K5qcQmbfn5tqoN0iP2snmzYDvTRWFWtQSrPtRi3URseDYzn43FpXHJJG8HvNIsZ7XSQIhf3sqLBBvj1MZtVroSbi/CoXSzd34lFs4nvUVTHIUH58/jc4EXzGr6tnOmxCcz3SdFkpMS0yi3b3qJ5@dQRyzfpuT0sFmrFq1wg2fHt/VS7Ll0a5oFoVmUM1FZHecyt2fDUfZuzjfM2WLciHcUaV41wqE8MyvfXrWEgdYzC@adMFjcFO7Uq3E4flMZSAmrO@RGMldqSaFEWa/5cr6qctbpzeOtsTgRwDLUr4s6l0kPBhWmwo0Sk8w8ZVrqmXlZ7mQv0nI6XUqGr/Vw4nyYPTufdeVWs1U@7/Ja9K6TjcQrnV4o3M2U871qdNRLVMuJaCnLNDrz6xrXzSVlrs8r2cHFPKqnSuFMnG1Na@fXg0ZfLSvZdHsmZSJCQ5sm2rykNsVFPMFehXyDfupCTYei1TjTtHJWs1SYRnzqZfEqXJ3PhZsOP47w0vOt6RNuF/1FpSXymtIvPde4RmtcysqDQSueERqhSqYeGi/MKa@XqkwqV1W5XGk2KUz79XbI1HPnerIzK3ez1arY0bsRXepU0jMpNGm3766vmxV1dHM9Oq8lOpVFlx/EWpZUi1dmFvMMJk9rUmoWOrOcZEqD2uRZPZuNb1pstHk2KjW7E98gdXc7icg3lVCpnGlJ/Lh43UtYzfJMv7pQJIUdhSs9lpk2q4uFJaa1fHl6dTuTWotFWs6Yz9zskuVLZ8XcjeVL5QvpXKVR5w2lUjkr5dL8aHo1Ld0kfOKiftWNycPnO6aqqkrYuKsriUwoYoabsdwiKwzOQuOzzKhx0UhxOtc8b11dXXJ9RRgJidtKLt6@Etrp9MXl/ELiW9WqXr1sNpiKT725u2uwlYZSSkmlYq2hxYoT46rdTvBTLX3Nh4rRUWdammWmV@Nxe5S68N1aIh/RFqLI1aZKiRXPQXaSjDieVLPlqjkPPy8Gz71JTrtppdL6WTydnUvdiThZhNK5iY81C7NpNy7ryXDjdnYm3QpXvd5lLdOP6BO9Ec/GmIuUdKW2Otn@VWouXp6XWoWxJda7najsM0P6oHGdbppNYS6fCfH@pGneKtD5JD3WyGRTpnKXS14asi@UFDKM0L7iq2ypH7spX3S1aXZ21ZrnYMqR5KRqKKbN1dY4OVTPL83MZfv5MpnsNTvnQyh43L/rC3LTl@l2xGtJKTN3N5etYb46brGD65urRLV57ksuIsbZs6D1z/jUvLGohEKilOpNiuNZRC8JybPkZUVQLmblWlMSe/F6@Fo5UxdMTk30Q2mJm06mKuubxzLJfE/KNMuqkWsK5wlRq/IsO2vfWZX2TfIyfBa6DtVH01DYvJqyIelWlee35dvbcJfJTMxLvV3nJnnfuZW@rQ9qwpnCltu14kKbl/Jhs5kuZ6XL8XSul@ayEbkTSmdZpSrIHJglsXivYTSHi8ykw7SlWSmbSSbuwucgQaappKa3UV4UTL03G7Clq/G5MhuMhy3DN5qxNd/d7SyW6rf6JiuUSo1ycZo3YtqFOVCZeFwIn7cNPWHWnkfzYtbK9VtNJZpNtXqdyvkte9WQLlPX2fpdQoxV2eKzmGrX4yGhFGsLLFfTRhMLRiShN2RK81DXEBTR4BPjynMsPx77uvPJ2PLpd4mzy2S7N8xyE4H3RdId7ZmftS6UkFxOiD2z0p5ObgptsBDV1qSpMoW7ph65lM@l@nmrcjXkqunawmIzqbZwE@3dGpykSpNaxIpdFMVeQpBy@bvhIHdefC6GbqXn0JRTjOvrSOGcYxKSL2NpXYVtXevX6iLMi@nbSvJq2l1kR/2yJJ4Xwznjthbv1i95JQ/DqPxcCumtwlnprttR@qykqZV6LRRi7uLhfPum9sxNutfVRUObnRu9i3RVidxIRVWr3rS43LXBlhOZwnV2ULvLzpPxqqF0xEYv2VBHvrOIJvBptRRnEuJEzLTabFOUI1xitujwQ5Hl7trDYfKcXcTNBZtWzekg2VukOmcjrn1X1s4a8yF7NprdVTM33Fj0cVxV0Jlra1GNnZ21fZfzs2axpzSLksDyo/nAPM@MxYtp5zqe9iX1UMOX77b6s1K1p7fzbKLTSXL1SKQdtZ671bl5XWZaudJ5JJGbWzMpPxyXZ8lzPR2vz2fN62h0eDeYVZL1eC024ybaMJ/RC70Yq92YCXXWOO8VMmJeupLMq0VHGDHxxbhcLCTzvpjI31Zv70JSnn2udxWr35MalzeRepwVYueV6vTuLpdmRwlpkC8qZzAmTvmr2bw@uB12ritmRGa0yq2vGF/EF/W763JXrbYvrvqdaS@RqBrnrUFqvLjVa3LNpy@axY52lquOlNziBgQuXkvFBk0l32zLN7laqMJY8XZ6CjY4lynJ8x5bjIUuJTV0MRudpW5G7fjwdtjKTmq3s@EgXk/EtLG4SFjt59hYbCZuL0Z1VujcTvu@8Bmj1Rfzm/x11CiVp3rJqmriZSgZLt0Nm6P8uOkbZS8LHSvbDumdcLs0HfuyMbAKkletVLjcuRxkisOza/P8OpxiGgV5Pk4OzuJnvioMJuOBWUm2lLAyYdus0ppOxOEoxJdzfMuYdZqFUrfcDSdZ3ScnptZl/PnitnrHW3pUZRlzHu9Oed95HiyInHwbq/talh4awVwkdDOJXKq9SNhUb@p1wcpqiWEzkhKjBaOlaq2ZNmiF5euzxHAqyJcDJiMuulGlWWt3y7PFtJsaRrt8fdJMF27UdiSr6v2ZaXDx1GW4xT9XR0akYunVUlPIqNcjnpemvpmSyV0Z9QnT7ZXT3XbheSxNWtFKOpqe33RD0fHdZMCpi5v8bXhQ7aT70rTWji5q00ime8aptZGsj4wwG2q01PwwOWuei5fMxSIvzvvJ60y1FW1eDlLDiNIb1quh@bAiS8LdnTnmire90jXXLcZamevU8Fwy02KimZIuBuys3KncxbNdMRpifP3iiA1nS0LkIn/jsy4EJfYsL7iytUhJ6rzclDv13iStl7qD5ricOWczXHhyNquMIuc1NjLmM6Nk7tK4NRRGzMfSs2blKm7279JWK6pVw5OkfleVezfhbrXPC6NQPAk6@KrbuZs307XMtHRbPq@babW3EH3G9FI9KxYKGZU5l9rlZ/OZ16RxOtqslG6vn6/TRq8R61hmkZs9i@x8rlYusoIwv00XzWG5dVFXi4nQqJu5Slz3uyW1qVXlyCUjpBLDmwSr1oWLcUiMVtPRwnPrTHguTuI1bahaQiN/x1nlGii7YqxZ0W@no0W2H5JmkWj@xqz0uvod9NbBggmPz2u33Zo0UGfT2oXVuoyM6tywNVWGcZXXfdF8qlLhuV4EJ2GxG00dacplz7qplyeXBsv2F/GxqJ@JlzJTCuu9dLEWvwjzZ2e3uVSTGz2XxHDyKjpOT8OV2pVPjYl6rtgbKaHssDYQr2WYMrTj1cFFqF6Wm727cfYmNa8zi9uOlFIv2lPtMjuc5oaTQaM5i8D0qtEqmWa9dmN1i5Nw5yKhdCr9biNXyF4LWZ43ExU1m68M9XGrM5qeR2PMoBC5GVwlLuRefJgoivPby7Geql4sitn@edR3q14krVveUp4ryuC53LGsznNCbtWvL9h2JiGooed5wrrpt1mTOU@O8mdRMbEo9rlEUx1NxuNupaZqxXn1@grYnAhHGmcdNq23r6tWq3suCjfnTbD0LzSxWL@50OtnN@fdcVdllAiIb5Y1Ls9KZuEmN7zjpsXavCNzvmHlclqJJWJSquObxEbl/jgXi7UTo4vypJDTjfjsCrR@rzqvlsRa@YrhRle3@aHvQuK4pHG1aE2itbR4E@9cTaVpNJZLz9R@MtkMza4vzoTrZEcvTkfNC653zU7vUkNzxDf5WlrQpAqTedYj89zMyodi@cv4@c21OIhPu/lxuJie1tvFuJUqS@129Hlamw7FcoGTGrPJNFwtVK4tNRqbta7vhpfQCjFG6M2u8wnxKip2Q/LiLmsUtI7a5NMh9oINT5uta5/WU5/Lom9YDRciejwfmlV5mBnfZcYX3XinOVDaZ5nzVJ/pRoW8r2HGi3fx55vnK9m4GfgSI1A5Sak2ub4Ck6RjNRvR2bWUuuUWrWyyzXcKCy5/yaaj5@fjVDEcviilSreMWY@NQFqep@Gbi5wSvq62GtGxL1fOzbr9@l2zlp1eJe9uuVG1XZ9c4GQswoamUmVQa87LhVlTFuP5YS0vZRhf8XpqVlK6VMu18gZb7UqF6GB4flY4E8eXwniWV32hXrE5nzyPR2Ly4krhRUMt1Kx@WojcJoeRmVDU08@XLWZ@zucvuGyylTSGsnAxKDfNgTlp65Kcjj7HZj6rNqjKl7FcrXGjDpr9ctkQslfhhCnmhvVR/K45mHUmYr57wUhWaiIos7Ny3FIz84J807y6vujWQ3OhmrwoF4xZqMMWnuuhicU2k/Vqo9cpG3JpAAOn77apaUkFVIrV164ZXu8XQ9NW@rKb7JnZs1CydDGrNOWyL3Sdrw1yYXNi@Nj@qBLOLbT8RUSaJnq168tRyMhOun3fZTXB3g0y2rTMxKxupM2bw1RN4m5vW6yery1M8yrZ7PgurxVWrIXvEpnzBdfoRPTuuH@bvB2dTZ5vb6@eO636OTTnjU@M16@emd715bmZkFIC121msqW0NtFDF8aoJkVHJe22Gb6VfLezXHH6HL4MFQbFDlcu9xeLjHBhtNVkbtS5yvLzQTPZYiL5Sqh7FxH1i2bu@bbQHw@EbGkmRG60c9N3Ey3PxmdGMhHnoqkJb0Zao1HLl0wrsi8R6c/74Ux@Es@xXaPWZvIVX7atadALandxvsya0W5ZscxmolHPp2rZQva8dJm/kUqpepG/ufHdXhez@XQjfnHZH0Yvbzkzw2au@oN6mBmUssMua1nJsVyXC2b@zMjN@nfD69G4M01MSubtQr3kx3JvxEm8PmyX1EQ8fd16jlVCkfwVm79bKGo4EZulmK4gdS9YpTa8aSfl/Dl7q/RhAp0D@R/eXI0NQTLMfqoNNb9aqIlss9JrGedKvwoUKp2xLkijlDzsi5E7psbWk4VEW7mUhMptbZS47cg3jYtIQhrPYP56m1tcSjkWWr15W@@PQzfxPJiu0ehzsd0fXU/KLbMWy7UapWqUaT3XchJXzJdKrTury5UroV5hYjUTyfM8J4wyw3J@nulkitOC0Gyf@wa@cKMrTAqttJJvdXlzNr8LpUJGWhow8UH8KiPlOGsaa0lGNHvRr0R4pajNKhdJfVSrXoQzF/lrSRsaocx1evmJt@apkRyb96R0@qxVvM32mPR1NjcItyRTqKm@aZGCZQoK//tffFSIaBgqBWMmmtwl9M3JzjEXR185eIKePIGPt2@dO4HOPpsHCUjO89VAC5TjdzXxCeFDuxC6txnEY9xxa/Ho9d5igFseJ0AveI4HOaBHt0tbG6EuAzOvyPgoq18jgO540h0U3Aejjyf/yjyEL9DgX6IENtEn6jyUN95v0kY5gud84FmGocejjS1PD7dJDRIITcarEvDT7/oVnqrwA2SkW8D5SsG7a1s/dLSVH4gzdZWeNOIKBF00q3MqBmLaRmG3JsavzmZg6IEsy421r7yYhme5ZCieoud7ENVv@Uf3qUf/gXDiIqIl8@rIHBvT7rCn9ScSUYg@6MyE@eKZkFiURKCs8A/Eh2Vy8ROWHhuagN8kSYWck6Ho5xM9BRnPx6LnDOLx125CAqvTpT4SLw348efQdfRGSsnBaCmF9iEfo/v444l6Ejoa3auPR6rP57V8J5aP83kw4gfOe6SPHU/Ee@uRPrXPHpCr5aP1eGw7@v5qEqlqqtDX3Cahry3dfOaEngO27EAjXt/sTxNRsDRjM0ZCeeJHWx3xbRTuEvOvcsraEs6a6yJu3a1OJVDwhc/482Ecjx69TccafviAR2gcOb4TmxX4wujjjiILh8wHyk/cAsfH6Q8PnUNhBIJy@@EDjZPtSJsWIpseTD5apgqaPncyyzbI07IuxxsoTz24t@r1fw/kEqoDMvmEL9kxAMwGsdm7BU4ANd0a9dpUYbgkqqt9UDzHx3uEp5yQj8u05Yk/CI9yQ8/debKITE/pgcsxcUDpGRjE65w4QWPvZXzojboSnLrtpA@D8Uin@89Bm16HI/hewCedl41VzqA5xveregiHzJCXRGMLYOAFj2Kb8Ja42TTLtkDHN/rwFdYH8VXpayCAYIE3jDnqRnz4APF1NZrng/3iSQ@xNNux0ibDyUur4XWaGhiHh/q6dfchoX5wRxBFt0SPNlIHkIp1fSd5BMkj3uq/k9xH3GPzvWQDkvF1lO8ky5BsPxO5O12DdHun/x0AC708QVyfLO3J4mXFYx/ogUeBvNgK20N8viVjVyJA7Iax22M7P3GORiEf7daxhW1LvKB/UrGyAVCkPU7nwfu1tNBUPPPYY8vFRpk2T8gX8s3CHOdIYPETLQnULpbvPdjCTzYIgP4HqpS8TV8Wbrf2qqJb8hOEYaeHrQ3MipCff/4aZY4gbssf97iUPruF0A93o4Y2t9Z47LflrdvVzrRwMu3O4xwds6ndlj4S63osO2V4rULsvrXu15KsdqEMQPxxMxpdnrzk0zrm3nwkhyvtseaj3S2@zcfwG@lBjyjaI/2ksw4K389VHuUecvIwInfWygLPCeOP3rDTXEEHtqFPAXrFzVdyJmzJjNNLf2llv682e0Af7dSUN0e2ohXANDx1CNxBHm@366ZOsJHtuw/teHwLoLyNTH4HmX2e3hMgsI6BBhzZlmp8OSbKatB@JhX0fCgc9VMXcxvkZc2mpbL6Hj79PXQuZJwzZI/xxUjbKonsYM0b8FW9kV@nr7vcq@rZmn535e7th5rdn9xII3krT1TqPsEoeUhCZHVw0xF5@bYe@ttx5su6@bbsHdPzvq5YNvpSEr9HBF/eYfQ3hWy7CuFHssVxJIFqhm8MSfQQwt2D0tq1/mkZs3S7tPv2uxYYUnW0nY402wiXCWAob@byOzbX6Vp1OqcvPllL48a/tsLwfYS2VIDJfsRsqnOczhXo4L0Zuzo6inJkMwWfZEcL01hSJktL2xbM4GW@oPCEzWwzGfkJfbqnaV3P0mByDAaKYXlCBwD57eOsVmaVbV6ui4fiHKOX9JxTPpbj7hHEfHSi6LgCEWh8OrKJRBz0aLc5wm6zYd/IJn1dJk3H0QiKWj59gM6KtvYhh6/jEXplAn3YmWmp8fFMMnpypaPn6Ui8pR5cWV5Fx1BsDntqfezC@FVDIMwpTLTX51vSNnjZscpgn@HpnG75ZXPqIh/JQbSJV42@9IL0Hq2oOT52YTErgX/5/d5HdmwabEdWWVGdgFHdmTN7RFTtt0Qd4qvEA0l0FMY3gTvahPplUydEEBNoKSwtqIpTj/O2cDxF1OVl7DPpqNMix@ARwNRvXBEnXbD67RNbdM2c0d85TBZCwbFuaTTFKYieXUd@ln9en6caok8ROTMGh5xjimcN48HnC@zYue0rGeBsA4nD8429GyjuMSdVuK4HlwvbDwl1/EnvHxkzKPJCH4lA2fvZnk5Bc1FJfmHMZdPjWWvICnx4BYKKfcqETn1HsQhqnZhzeg/Vx3sOA3YMdXFFuXfmKQx1CMYURdN0FHJ0BcX8x8AAm/Ef6o1cvlYL/v/FXetz4jgS/xz/FQpTk4MJGMhmbrcmk2wcMImrALO2SULN5lIEnMQ1PFI8hlC7@dvv@teS/CBMZq7uw30BW49@SS21ZKlbxfiQJ9Zxyl2eY8YVQXZYxyEI4mO8OK0Od4GyUXbALGBLfMcJcB5/WUZAq8QEVVhBnFJW8EcoOShV@e0VG3H5gizOIuHrTuptDllWlFePJ7KjILukWj5VraSr6cIpUez8UBr9wQCOIFrheEoU18LRiIiWsthJxIFHSETj34/xz78A501MvMwvvcovZfJNmS@JSkqZg8dZUuhTulDu3V9JuReRS4oVX@E6FsS002bvUuZ0lqL76K2yc5MWaVFS@CRuStkr44zPmYxSKudfW1pf5uxm6sQdPM7/IvNV/z5QLR9TmSl7msWPf0M1UMg@GNSVxY1eak6i0e9y@zHO4RFWwK2SrI725m4nlVJtiKjhpETDBHViVtuT4wTKflWPOKwzuZPPpzlTbUn9nt8kQwaneqVYW3QkJSXGuc@Ce@aZhPBw9m4KBMNERxNac0905bWqvE6BRaldjdbQnkKzCk6sbar4MY51/40frexZ4nS5d9szdyTlz5J5edMiKyAedHdz28WUHU0Ws2UoExVTb8wiCe71JsTtg0R7ihXo4BEjRYwzlPdB7qfLyXA3HifSA4UeKV7JPc5Rkk4KVHX3/V4TIvPF@Hf5g3HeH5NVOAqfhQWbus/e8I3MZZtFOF/MSQdCYnAm5sunp1Gk/LqJFV/nkHxWDz7iMkICMWU0mIaDC6KyfBFP6nIMVTKFC8gr3DNMMubLhwcZl10g8CsNrfcRgVyYhjVZy5DxcIN2IK@8hGIJP64YgEe07EsRIVtOag/vPMBKMw19sUiyei/1e7IgE4gYn7LPQ7ha/WQYfyyjwdfauTioVH6tVn6ppkSmt6or5i@HHHlem0g646BSrVQ@Vg8NozZ9WsurjflBAbAOSwBYFE1M9JfUN8NvCMxqWDRjcME5mf7zcPYtHJqG4YVD3gO@W7JE0JWX81B6UWY/r0gh2wr@7sncHc@LgpZdjxhe8I/5WfquHbBjjaKBO0RP4WwcLeRNo@m3aAgB6ntT99PRaLrijWhcWZLyQKVxuCChfCiILEnsl1bRwrYLu4slafRV/Pj@3fQb@5FWYiA7NYL7fb4AZMCJIiCkkcng0ylKCN9g1I/G6E5bCICXpUQCmgBibbgchG/SYDAR/yUNQjE2nA6W8Mzb1y1TptFvyrpC6h7OIhp9EwFzq3C1FO3UwMGF4wvfbQRXlmcLeu547qVTt@virCeCC1vU3E6Pg1qJC7dJo4svrHadUtuB55x1A5cScpZPNXOcYVjtnrCvO57t@8L1hNPqNB2CRuA9qx04tl8UTrvW7NJkfV4UBEG03UA0nZYTULHALTJWXc1I6gm3IVq2V7ugV@vMaTpBjzE2nKANZA3CZomO5QVOrdu0PNHpeh3XtwUYM@qOX2taTsuum4iO1XaFfWm3A@FfWM3mBqPuVdv2QHyGyzObqLTOmjZjYj7rjmfXAjCUPNVIeERgsyj8jl1z8GBf28SO5fWKCqhv/9GlQpQp6lbLOifmjPwPpELtUut6dgtEkyT87pkfOEE3sMW569ZZ1r7tXTo12z8SRtP1WWBd3y4KBCZk1ASDpEX59HzW9R2Wm9MOaM7odgLHbReoka9IMESlRVXrLGC3LbklIbleD1AhB26Aori6sCndg0xZWhak4JPUakG6GCEkIQZpNkXbPm8653a7ZiPbBZgrx7cL1GCOjwIEE3ivLELaZa7RTkSXfKTOauieW@TmFE5DWPVLB5Sr0tQDfEf1FhZb7ULJnHS5bGz95PbmB7zXX/nUVsjbTuJrbt0mi09GZ8kl6V2adH7LfrzL5NFEE2fSq/oKynPV7TC8Wz7cRpP7KZbmcTX5BXs8fygiOlEBYSH/NN4ITKs@lHOFd@9uby@tW1rn@re3heLP1MyQ8aMaygvrW6UKisfRtD/kZX5mbyktqJM95eu9KB0vp/da9uLNh4Iol4ehqobLiwCst4lUUAICNsTIyLca@xORQsmfmLN7RRwxY3OzSH/enM7pZ/J38iLnhlQCDc7y3EK5jDUsk4HIJyKmn5BwUBAVGYTPAUT3jNKch@HXh3wljQ5LfrVBVdB1uOyCloEP@cIPqt@FDxvVS5v1mVjcNWVjRbuD127a0TGn/KZEJlS7mDPmLC@39vivoKlhRGQUFiQqvsiqTp/k92R1@BeVe4WFo9iVOIcDaVnXzhUWc5WDw6ON9Is4XeoWbp0jtg3Nd1@43g3/XdzIAqRgEZZfJJJoLT@plsupOmSVsT0ZF4av@kcUWkVDmlMxVT@GPK3DQ750F5yuT5PxLHpOU0/D8Llntc66jQaNnKD28LePv/7zyFAe92eL66L87wEPAkCydMmKXkVkpnFWSktqZPc0XgXLSUX3QeuhIKIq6kbjxD6ZtLHnTGkjyPgachsI7M4RYWCCIBs5BAmY5QTu54e7hu6vWzVTdYB8htUCuBn3n9nC75OpxH1gIL1kjtbcas/4AexY/bWKxwypDqS6WDh@Wqyp59Ligse9XEM7HOC1DV8rRhEzp/vxU1@fQZKCwZjJXhhwB5/fVN9OtSLZtWho6Cs3O9ckInY3qdBBWjjkEqHoTOdag2ViRCnXqr/RY08FB0IWQj1YC5/E2IhrlnTwHrnnrBRDQb45OaYm2tuLMX0W2EgtKKLk/n82dExaG5gUeaBBbADWJ49iOcc5vAl9@o@C@Ev2VHj1Bpwj1WPVO/XcbewoKEfaJbp61xFkhISVBJThpFWMw9BFerpILM6MmP4neTD8/6NMtsD/TAtOgp5Ii8fhaLIMf1KSDFXKilavLJRopU@MpY6pJdJMJ/USMC/phnmMGVPH8J7lhyUSgWqdtU7oyZBi@S0CQCfHvkZaf@HAl5X4sU8rp1PW3R35pX82GYyf8jogl54qXsG9KbLNVdRH5PBSkJ/wKyKFron4Kqfs55HHDCy4aBS7W4v385yEsV/lMQdMlz/wpkes5dw1IYaq1vCkO1WUamnlf1YnjJJZZqhzX8gU/X6wr/hzCGIKZQZ8/QVEDyB89inNsBIb4TwBoVv5hqcX3uUXahZHsEgaAnleFgG755j373nNjKlI@dKA0w6gBJz3QxWz6S5crDBdjCR09iGSQBP59@zGBEjUXmRsRujBt2CS1HmSXcXU8zYl@mtMfXfydYKAwqHc4tIlzEwEqLQLVlO0@hwMavRzfOcS5PsQ60kWvzNhvyoD@b0SW3O8cicsWOm/nycSIYtzBeuS5qFESv3BVyTmdB@NVqXomf4YV0lxrmMa0ZqBI9ZtM/pfvrsgQF/ZOAMrcn9O4k2kT3IiO36vzRc8Sd2Nn3p4UvvMx8QUEUcpODCrzCCQDLsJhzRfaxvT9x8)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)

### Explanation

Aheui is a 2D language that uses Korean Hangul characters for its commands.

I have placed the Aheui on a new line after the symbolic brainfuck. At least this interpreter but possibly others move downward initially if the source starts with non-Hangul.

The Aheui looks like this

```
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희

밠밠  Push 7 and move right, twice [7,7]
따    Multiply and move right [49]
빠빠  Duplicate and move right, twice [49,49,49]
맣    Print as Unicode and move right [49,49]
박    Push 2 and move right [2,49,49]
다    Add and move right [51,49]
맣    Print as Unicode and move right [49]
받    Push 3 and move right [3,49]
다    Add and move right [52]
맣    Print as Unicode and move right []
희    Exit
맣희  For Incident
```

Answer (score 5):

## 135. [LNUSP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/LNUSP), 5542 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRc
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoO4O6O@MOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희

♈
♈♈
♉♈ +-------+
♈♈ |$0011 \|
♈♉ |/1000 /|
♈|\ 0011\|
♉♈ |/01 00/|
♈|\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♉+-------+
♉
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pRcxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._ #]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002252 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 5664 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1bb@tKdyD4vIn5B3mpLfscSdaFpO6yLe@tqy1bN@tq@XJ8KIqUKFEkTVLXfXyQeUkn6cZMTzodpL/uzpdkejABph@CHgzQjQ4wwPRr/4rvNRjM9w@@WVUkdbFl732SyJZYrFq1atWqVatWVS0We5wx/N3vDvAH1VR5OZBVE5mCYaK@Ls0EPYgyS/SZk4xoKExRGCqtD6YTQTGNY@oAsQhJCi/14R6Z6lhQpJWgQ3wIIU1XBzo3QeaQM5Fg8JwmGEidmtrURKq4P1sYofxEHUkBnHMiKQMAMwVd0wWTpEcQaikyN@n1uRcp0RcFajqkGygnyD9NfjIRr04mnNI3ADKGUK6ayZfSLzDEESqruiFgPLxgGCqOTCC0yAv8C9AkgHK6pJbSlfMXSSyDzoF0TpOFBeJ6hqlzvCmpisW7mq72pzyulzkUICfmhSjJgkHxQPMZ0uwWCOIAOkC6wPUtMEpUdYSzoMlYRhLiNQ31ZG4Y5JEsAWyBSSABsw6tIF0eGmihTQCDoU6EbRINpAhCHxmawEuixJPSkbAwBcUAKo0gkvgxmkuyjPqCDBk2JPF@QIamxlaURUCQ6qsUgg@vvajA@u5QABhFcJggaMA9zAQVMxs44vBirnOaBkQCIxtAuClNQGYk020ggTMkLJWQxRCUPuGftpZXFXHKdi3RTOIQB/ROdYLbEHTcCEGCFw0FXQCU3FpiPHNdMoEFmL1pVBM4HTV1QfDuyu5OkVCYikswcUWCpPlOT935asENzWjlCHKaSR3o4eb1JcWhYAodPp7AN@VynVD5Sg59ObzHYUtUoak13cN5UepnZND39wJ8F2yPHujPFGClgCsyolXNpLmABgQGTCCQ5nAQhwKzUFCTtwpGpy/aYku4LKg@tAYqKqjtJzXjp7qOu@OGqdwYKi2rygD4CZXVpwrmh4JiDDQBr0Jv8iNhBlxTFauN1DnhcHMoQaMZuEm2OoClVAhDQa2A7Nkcdco1VHlK4CCnYWIBBK5AVoyxKKI2EjlJxlkgHaOyqNYFYyqbOM9U6eOWB6Uh9IPIIYNX@xhoos6gOA6QkgjoS5OtHkiIAmBoCJVUFSf95l/@2/5gAHjSPK/qfVtc26iv8kT9cYRY0CkIC6yqcDIhC@D8uHQrOxQw42Spz5m4eGVpF0GIIKXO1ancRyoUqM8l6FpDbgbdURQF3hQsIbc0ph9NuLGlNyRLcqHiE64HDUsKIGWTagfQ5yy0Ei9QB0RmApOpKSZQQMsjt0H/4Pl07Pn08V4A4rxB79EhTQ9OQOCCRyQK7tzvSU47vaXRQLmYnKFKfUpbmkNVCaEAj1x8StUExePeweH2u/We2xvE@szjPZFSfFCUlL7HDTKegXLd3hM@xd9Jxw8nL3JvlwhY5hgL7q2Ch/e6KNA4pE/M6AknKUFtidoBO7SVphqPmOM4ObgVjfnyMm5mRRyQAQOLpYrlA9RQ0JAFQfMwQdaLtQSG21ttnLCvoi9w2BU@lh587gO3b7vqBAPUdKeiuK82JRVrLVkbTkFHA1MUQwPtrWPR5TkQHgMrcRNGbT/qEbEmmh8UC1GJc8GtC6gHetQRI9IjrR6H8wewnrQxbHqQA7fboYX@Vn8GXQBd2jReKWVZnUPBhDY8fIEGUXDh3ACaCDJbFUpbFbJKJDG7VRsroFcwtp6AEoGeBH0B9zpQ7bbob9URwMMhCwawWX1lSwVNuCVg4a0hcdNvkCRCl5qAltCXiBew6gEdJFjjCi5kSrqhAfYKtlyYQCga3e1qr3qaqdPpwC3o6hX9bofClU/vWAkwAInCHMmcMphyA2wyKZCF43lBM219BTUxTNBIL4cdEhmwx9CgMaQOP78sm4wl9ui6VQbW9Vbr2SMih5WMbTQFZNCpiLPNPtSXdNBO8vJl6QAwe1G460cMskPAj643SHAMARAyYSHwUxOUGwjyfCjxQ5BdTJ1iqUdrLHpZPERtlw4KPiCui8bEsGffh6ggvY7CZLyJIoBb9DUeGGMxqrOdCNL42xHvY@aMyR7E6ppEGA@2YoM0FwTZ@wrOiaqoe5ACI9doMchuitUOYJA1sDEI45djfZHOurYQ100EbQbaA3o@yN/QNDXjGIYLyRxOe0GQFLqpL4tmVcHCQpv6UjJVK9yT1R6oZwP6J@2UQPPTnrR4USESt27DkUHNwA4TDZSCAfxpClLncYsGKE4Sn8XAW0kuosAJCuvXBYAEKAiM8ogGUckFUCqNpcJ7XEHSlYLQ6Vx@5MId1@WFAM615ktWnWAthDrEPsAGX0YHzSWCtrJ1P1H93N4Rbz0GEPPO7Q6OVEnxfHF//PjRfew@Aw3/8eMnCJ3i0Ccc8kHoEwkFSAjDBXGI5PCTEE69Izlw3IP7@c7BvPA@4GZb4NFpJWke7u74OPzg5@5Y@xrCVy@oOtBsAB3AF8Dj9qZSOOj1us7mUNFgT7RqX7c42yfSUBeUASUsNFU3UaWayz/W0s2LlIueGjotSz1agfH1cQI9GOYyrj35YVLiZIdgXVXNFGkwHE@gCwBkT9YoU51Cn4f5hzSRzCKZ/cgKFuxNozmpWSh3g6AmCSZlj0YbWccToU3bQD0IfHF7TiTq6mSt4QxK4Icqch2GXdiW35mP4mHfTo3g1Kk9G92Kj@P4CZ5JBnlqwPMooFq360gbMIEB8ewyCJM5auDzYUgy21xH2pBJghLPOIN6z4n8wjLPOH493dwaR7Yx7kt/OxPhzZ75sV1oDJfYV3uCvIhFAoIsBs3FKojVQixCWRcU6L8FsScvtVjty0CZ0McDC/FFAqdTFoVNGKtKMDVBJckgywnbzUmtO8I95bI6anh3FHJtUkIbk3G/nevaxkKEFgRhrGK1uAk9glEX3UEB0/TXOUXJGJKfHdBXFL1OIbmNSU8kP3sAjm3bCUQfT@QxSy7xNBCbb6oKk/45ASOjAEEGrJIUjq6TCx4P9tGzO7LtENMTxClMDemepODwV8ACyQSBFHs96S1Q4Asm3bnuAdOnvX1sA@EavjJ@0A7jzaluykLfvv733@9DA7xuniG3hCkNP14HHoFvuKkC4putZWfFN@Rnf8sSmNFUljjCBhL6Gkqew9NOTl4H9qPGqhcFAkNOh8ZdOo0Lwol/YBh9R84synVBnvYF57q/EMLiXRPLyq1IE1IjuGJ7kYyXb2R/YSBa@fG0XZdVrk@wWMspkrBpbatdhAU3gMrRWxoJNOE30OnYcWizfgIGizm1fvGSydfaVdLwdz9XjneFjIlyPVaA6SbXk97gIyYj9pZkWx0GmxgBUebGVvARB/dX1qqOLg0GYFrZ17fAwI6GqY7G8QI9J5c3lYwyNTSrMXDoHXy6bP2@BeKs8K4DbwFCNWXy80sEj4gCD70Dk4oXLQNbLJJeMFXmektshg1/uQThAslICgomxft8TBgPqutZ7mZ5VNPezo@tAJI/mdyf21pJJQh4VRQF4Wu9FkYeacLJgVB/K/imEnbM1k1oD@iIm3Fg0MqcAQJi2mwWZtAs5Oc9ocWDCT@VOX0TekdkN@Q4ixlvzYc3eTSJV2XJlkzn5i1t@HImsUGD18rJzyYrvnvN3z4Y73igDqxD@zu0ypt4TvqGHH2DgrKmg3jCvSUYQfUt3vHqHH/f7L1DdSZYv/sHrdVeqr5B/QRkIhkwIXydvc9/TVzx4ib52c/F8V6qTF7eG3@MyqqqDwXFQKEgg00chazIw5Aty9b8tFmsvi3ThiSrBmqQ3/d4AUa/YVi/@6V5m20SpwT4odXH1uH92fYSRQY4lCa/bzQuJw9UOZYY0Bz8vCkBU13EWt6@fquGW2solv2qhlobPKrC2tc3VfsY/r8mHGStVcdLEFvBd@yoferMnrq@XUGYE@B1xf2VKzAJkjNIWzO1txpA54dzbulc/wGjx1vcdUYPbUnMZbDncIZkAgKmbpnQ/5DSIu@X1v82HfUKbfxrldhq3LEsgMYmv6@aFIUY9hfmYBnm2zWWKE@FqbBXg1R7IwHE5j3d8e1EMXY1Du21DRqYh7dh11ArezL4TVTj8RzfvatwOFmCTv5Va2avqtHAxtbw5LkGgRoOvM44UKbaTuNu8a4@Vervc26oOT1b7e8QiVN@qUZKfN1m2jHDDYF83zLZ8xMVprzqBGwI5Rva30ZKloGs3x3EJGaDeSThFSn9XbzHaL1WCfYr2CPQqtLYCOBlrW9TPKG35uoEOJmE2ZgimEv8@xa39ynSnqrKv6R1QJ/2JWymgfGJ/RG@1kqvbB972RptViUMvMLRE99aj7DGGnviCNzDk@Q3G7oGVTLJ4PAtrfxqne@dUWtr1e9r80cYscmij6HzTvgteuu4c7PBRDD@LsHOihjtBN5DlgyGv8U@0hyjlyyq4oVYa@l141Bx8EL/aEvglNQPGPxQmAjk9h2Ln@uPpoZzeRNooeLvnuQgTZZF38inSdDhFfy7s8y7ZRKZqiIYtMnpAwHPVWSBA2vUin1LyTqrrXuZW5xwA6HwVcnaLDngDU1el3aC@xcfjq09Bh6yfUWNWNNAVRkLS8O57jeWlzy053TyLrZ9nZzHK5tf7dVBeu8K81dsPmWoDpWhMNRJz1jfvdU3QCJNy6fqvUoA/UPOGOMdXFshaWYJBZ7Q1mxvaGzzWVZl@Vv4jFWjpShVdf/yax77UPUh6y/Cu@R6kGBfvrpSByM4YRcZyt/qRUNhCgOVoZqqJgTI3V56S5VWo/YegfYuDvH6WW8MG37bXQniJN12TjHWHmAHRYXXBbJN7GwbogO8eT2dTGXOVPUgInAeD@fzeb2UlQlPKwcKgDlQxAcHb8xb7j0Ggsm@SWAlEd3docMvi2PmmH1GKeQ6dqGHBwsr2SLOLzTiPFO3st4dcg@pQ3cg4D503yvHiHETUEEGK38vKLcDJ0rkYtG5qTpSuAnxBcBhp6YnlsMBTL6xT8@QU/qygFowTJElCVW3ts0t34wmXof@b3/Tt12dQC8ZaCIZYNUNFOyep06EoTr/ZJVrl57WNA67SmEc8yFeaMWlB7JpZMwlE/Qw8XBS56hVaCZshwnbgRBualgbbVFhNSoeIbEbj2k1mkVNXxUssbALXudyKsWr8nSioLnUN4dGEGbSCi8Qh4z1FhqEMJhi6rgj9P2oiPoCXgXsY8LIKCCr6pjsDWJK/tvfWG4ikChhEcJhp3jiJbZVIsIjG/HN4Hl1ClQ7SFaCrtogHsxk0ERTbGCBUAtWvBfxQ474r4AkBhzvDVyM5cGRTTdQII/c2MsR7wmfSKLnMF0/b98xD6mf0YQW/vvv094vNt9c3wXirOHyIwfk5BnL1XYyA8mbVDdyHS5cdrWwPx1xH1sLle0c68Fh0lyON8aEuOIRuRPmxBuDbHIqWNFiHzfFgP4Bt16C2uo0qUPP1BrNAw0TRbErKAyQHIQs5z3i1YQ9C3CWwwX6CQ2xrAR4xEYZuLMYImNnlkkq4@zihLc32uic0JuSRedZKBgKp0h1Dh9Tp2ckpAt9FfuW3f1wvwgxgftFPP9AGw5z7u8X3zGhG@CeqkOu72ncgfKV3JfD4Bnz008GTK9drmf3ibXxCL388EutWMs3mulmqwHcfLYqe1BQ9Qm30RRYFjSZ46H7yMRpD9iiS4Lxde2x1iDrOwD3eNAhh06xW6/Xu05Yg9qsdgVch1ZwDQIj7nbur2Tfl98QttJfA9iaSZSQrUVRjQiSLTNuY1uD@h3Zwu2Cu/sUdLbDEbyXvEcVEh65UAq4FAAufSOP0OtaWi34iURAM36dUe/j2IcCeLWBeA2AmbQuC9fXSrcqt7fyz/8ENdZgXPvH1pjgeLfGGOK9GgPgJhvJUUgXS616fjcTiNPGQxtsGR072Iukb1m@npZ0qbZfoaOZYOAZWq5CnLzRrQaaSYbUkwUibyIeGcDmJt2R7D0ZWLsgrMiCKC0boMn7fVBNvaWJNRuo9CDxN7CcDgIKch0As4LrgdaPXBSGNVKv/ctAc81hasr/aGU@JHAEs0Ht8Ye9F@jf/Mt/a/nA3psQ/iM7LEL4X1jhH2jMoNd@fBaNa9ZgtrSLNWTAcGlVfMIttuqERyw8IkrKVEDSBDg4IwzB4Baxm/pu8Hju2sBPaARgJla9WNuS8gT9wYO9sI5pGhsYeG4ZJHvWwgLaAZQ1ccp6mmKfZBgg6Fg0FmFpIDIwcxAGJAthQLMQer3HIGvUTNJSP/Z4dHp6ilwGz8lCKnZiMZI@5H4Iu35cE3oIsJRli9whyANZNjkg7czO5jnkfKwXZ8Vdzs260cMJmBlWu8BI5SEBAPHiaMXmhwuGQtVmFTS6IixMos6Xjo0FBo5CnGsEyzPdQRQARBZu7Dr7UnY3W6HYRWRLmoPbzeDqYLAGBjt27ROdux/QvXmvPNge1AgE5i/3CJIC4T/e41a9lp70a4dez0t3XFwb9LmhqHh7vADUIk@IDoVpNubd6ikuGxXQi/vFT4ASegL0LF6QRqpmpLP54mW11njlkEog3S/B3Mh9duq7DwT9dw/rgPuF1DtMzRToRjlTcFi5TdVmlQlDbJaaXpK5r7SXlL5Resfah35dNkl4VRDLfCtiMpkLFMhq7Gvsm1R6CzBr7ZO9KtXj/fJ893B6dq8cvCr@p32@@gfBIyxcELo3iKe@G@3ROUVnd72JH6Qygo6rVsi1eRJl7Yhm3W@i33YpXT@WtfErdfbxsU9p6IzuCzNamcoyFXxjhx/qHqStoohTpUWYQy/oGodUFpO6KZCnXq0UblOD7Lq8foLM9q1bM6lqTU@JzzynwMxEl3gL2iAK2prEEgdvmMYUzc3MB2ZTeHWHTPCWZDIDqmK969iXyBoHpztOf@uUhjCRAk2HHqw4Nn6ioMiw/@MQ6iZLvRMudbdAa0@191xIg4YmS6YH@24ugniSCLXxeHEF2FNZwK6fp8kH288UOe6gPuJRWpsCv2qqhjYT85zghOowN0O5KSAHMRDQ5XQCcCK51AU8SgioogYgM/DR7RBxB6V47DoEJ/0olB4cCou@NICRxuP1g0r6jmU3vqic1wcTajfoYYtV53g7dZsxv8h/dotj3B0XlJS@sPDgZyWOHzB3IN4978zcXtcrGSBOvLZHb/@lN6@jLDjT7rUbT9gXCiGZXCuC3b6TTAaHBoU9CWFeASU2TL0EQRhDPeKE05BnStyhDRRE5NZz71H8hql7UeAMj2dzpCCfj8xI4EISgojkFElIkvGCoAc/ROShU9DOONZQ@viykjR0xwaDDxAmhXjRIV5TyIK5gWfjXgoMTshyTNDCAAx/x5iiOcy9MEXW9ZAUS@EFAR2g9iaTjjwYkg4IvCC1Rmffo4022PRAi6vJ5LHdGrvqMIlALE73aAxAu0fNORYn8Nd2BwOuYSUGUFmYakqgUD5fCYoC/dUDMjOB3om4KQiZ7vU7T7D6Nw9HkRIOLBIvbP8yIHT3oam8@4usgj1zSJ@Qee3JM4z7P97jgV@0h/4l/Xt0kD754jmUU0sajDHvmedwmGJ94SOf71A58hwq2Bz5/ns8HX4@BGvnMegKuhYAFDiUvScgz2AdpQ6Vk0Pu1HPYT4WOSA649fm8XyDDzwYd/HLIPdOH34M14YcY3eqdnkPDi7sDEwyyz0Af7iGHtB9k5ovHhVzk@VNc/KHk82EagoePmICf6fuGj4wr9w2azLxPbCOXHkwcNbJrq6xb4tXztBYD7ejjtUaPEj9haxvh0QHefmZqT9o@@@h3vztgYzCJ@hQLe9RPofDHowN08NlFH7l015f73Mx9x4mh4NNDbVyr3XjvPSCR7oNs1cVGXOgHhI5o6oA@Yn6K0/SPP/4I1ie6OwueBR@8dwH3w51ncRaPH/ljiSP/ZzdrTaJhQsayXk8o5KXRfQPdxznuyBcJfVZOJEnSjH4fvuoQP8EHllgKS8kH@HjYmtsdDbsbP2AP/k@fPsIf@YfP@hb/fiQxdjQBef356EWepwV1cLb45s8jfKsZEmzTLBu6Vz7gp6ljHz9/gDoLPvI5Pv5MJjLIFU@4VPUzhkbDA5aNIvUAhr6FgHposQjgD3XAH6wgiT1Ykr9HHGbZJtfkEP7v4b@6if/aY/xX5@s8dfBzKuX7xs9iHQoGH50QdfDj6Y@pf8SHOoApyMHZ2cPzsy9wF/zhxHdygr/4H7qvEzwhHysExT/4Ar7Tu9PT4NnZ4izwcHZHHXyhDhbP1EHIBbJ2f0QdpBandULjXe7MpvbJnlWXIHwaeLirlcBybvpDp4GDUCGd9YcarcwBC3fRzS1ODOPbej6dq7YAulbKpxv582I736pBvPHwePb5sy8IbfA5ePYAlCy@8535UqZpotvHoyB69/O4J2TdUge5s0WLDpwCsSU7pk6KCdzD3b0XCvuJOrg7uPN8Cn0KMTIzY9gxOy6r1fV/pBqrfi5Xq5AoLZiRqjNDZsj2QS4WjNBilsxywUzUKtuHoAB/zASCEiMumAGjMArLbiN7539SVctVFVCpkM1cMCbGyohwHVSrZUAmQsEj@JMYhlkAlQtmBv@MjIiQsj88MqTSXub@nrpDrh8F6PxB1h1k3MGY2y09RGPa05fnUOzpjpgG0eTDnbCQzAcX8rsf7@@SyaT74eSANu7vaUsfukIR1wkGeX5@fMylm@nHRxqvlCxOD32ffYHP8Emd@U7ty6eD/hlmbfD04z3l9sw7nQ7@duazuRUiASuus07cviEB@MzeyLsbWOwXBo/nLvrw5dnr9X64d5@4rZp4PEgAg9fjYu8XIRGFXF5iCSdhGGHD2FiJRb1nZ7Eo3McS3oCHIclWlnuXpmn3riCZWQeJU0kqldZ1bkmAIjCS3bs4/fHedRd6SKWSURIdDSRjSNUDybDX5fX@wJ6e2mWEvBDtci9cqu5GX563/zxfnk895OPFf14vjrR/z7weSPZG4W7xxbM49Zx6cBxE4Vxfns9wkMB9gdCdx/vgfX624uDX4z21cJ55gXd4@eCf8F81kKEh98HzAbZAFBSJej29peCNxDwJX9L@S32ECnhcYXcY6uVyc@67u89H4aN45O7Tw9HDkef0KHh0f/awo9@97gMEsuzIXoo9wHyjDoIndRcbcrmxLJ7gfQBVFoKyOkDh5MmuMLgfPUcvPwk26Tvyfb47Siatso@OfvoI3QbQQWEu@ByA/CIPOj07XQvVBqX3DL5fkM1kCD9/ATmz0sCg8dgr/ff3C4b0Ry866aUOvxxwzycEP3p2uU925JXg97hPyFaQ64vrkNPv2AfXs@vwS@8ZW35HrJcYGNHIyclRxArHExBmj7zW6maUgTsnDCmCwfGk554cYHFyA8@9UKtUTxhIClh7O0zyRaNROgS/i@9i@dCCOsFbJtb@jCvgsjoQSiQJvgNkGEkKJhc9aPk5ijMwgsoypyNVFD9a8TBLQj1BAENVkGW81ocnEWBLy/05TFw/UgegaMBgMQT4TGqcMBWE@XQ6F9afrGQccyPkGcEkGH9@@@s//wP4/g18/8S6/sl/TEbx729//b/8b7/5i7@CyP8K3/8C3//821//m9@3vuT@7@D7f2/F/Z393YKzvhTg@ue//fWf/vVvf/0vfgXff29/f/Xy@5s/@0/W//9j/@HgX/3mz/4O/9g3f/An1N//7V/i/z/927//L3@J///3//Xv//Zf//0//w8k8G@twP/77/@j9UtB6X/@x7/5N38IlfozHP5nEIZ/O/qPIIh8Aevj20pHPx0yYLih@582kX@EfqJZGCEQvY4ErP/up3vsr8dakA7On2iGhWgL8o9/@@t/9dcQuwP5h072zwjiXkLaAuQU9EcA@Rc7dNqQf0SBnQn/H9FHKoTwFf9QrJX9IwktjqhoGITRCbObcDhCwlH43afx8e7Hp887URbuo33ABPATSf@4dwDBZRw5tO0r7KOTfy@GT@gzJMdRqwY/9eL5RXPr2synsxdUDGWqldyLS9QGiqJSvtBc38atVCdrdI2imy@VXt7al646RTyHOyB5sHxBjn4Jnp6yLHXWyDchollFbIgJUmc3aBFEtdq14XLBzBN3/I8oGvf7g8Eg/OCrn3zINXj4gwPCvm2SHVBlvDSdZC1PAQnngJAuJPHeKOiLuUK2pnv4gIGp9nYkXHAUDurSYAgT4rm6BjAMAyyFteXwyo7oUBegnyb4kVp8nIOJ50SSiBgqiLVZKJRMRBPJcCjhTyQTkSgbi0b9bMjPxhPxJOOH2VCCjSWiSdafiCTDkUgk6QeGRZNxmDsrfUmkaTCOWZcLkYCk8PgZslP8MJ4aHJ5RB31BlBThA1p4@t4PB30nAk0TyBVO3DPIRdMuNkbhvaOjRcoVCgN6FGagk7go1wrx6IDJJsIMGOI9fJNJxNOxsMv1SFLgk2Vcrj6@iTOJQibucgn4JppgmHjG5RLxTaGQZQoFl6tq3eCPy7V0bhgGChriu3yMwZ68LgnfZNMW3AjfhBK4KJdrbKVYNxPnJg5gCr4JhzEC5HI9rdFh5LpVVILkMq0bhslkXa6pVYsE/LlcTYIvDH8JyJS2kiKkghmSxOBblytr3UQIunMHA77J45uEfVOwUjAgoJPhridz/NjlGkBwoMO45HItSOxUAJmHEPZqU0zO5eLhhl9yCuQTh6awSi/Tgwx8spnHwWIwWJzzOEVqTgc7n3zBThm9TMEfkjJuThf7UybL6cBJWlTtj45TlN7y9WeFU57eTJG3UqrLar/axB@SMhg4CYPq@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@pg9PmmSvsqgYfT2l7meGMJusL92cnkVQWL5KASRG8fzz96PulnyDOHDz77CySnOHFoFefSITSBew308enk1mTxkQU83WAjANAc@L7h3ygZCoFSKkTPK9wHWh1frHg5SVejEL3VkVPfz4gs0pU@@L4MUwVstVyXMYL6x7uuEGeEL57QN6fK5L8JREOnJGVSSyiCFr6uZH8If5D4odyq9qqFj4zx4njxP293Zx@1s26SVM9foZBTKrnqQPjJ68aZX9WLk8OjjV3OOIG0@s@dWDVm417D85C8aDBLQ8ebP8/TySOZRXuySQjxKIDsbP7me/czCZkxQiKSvxefzCQQr9X/vGnQ5p2u8EUPDy7@@WsfCSLZkBC7OfAqfV/Cj8oW7UodMWiLi92qzR@ePzh8QDBTAO5QlHckXw0suYS2zMfz@JI@eFIgT/hyCB/gkBulaPTM4gyIMK@FzCE4D2iafo6BMZDMhlLxA6o39H0e1uSkLpeoxcFQTemk32L9GldKnN4A0NZL9RDoDxdCTpcndPGHCsDYTMD70JhO2M7zjY9tqLIIX27cUuDxo5QOBbMPXycGznlEYlYO3nwXNokDi3oCB@RiP09vdQX6gPgmvIm8aGCnxOK@oCdefCtx4Hzo@8N04sdHRgv9eGDrWcNM2iYjxg5zmRHBtgT6pnC7OH6fQPh/RPit2A5iXLYNUbVrCcs5CWyMhlkILEMJuLficvdIvgIiRYVUJsjREoklOPKWcV/sMB6UxGTUiiW8pAHpZBI9uHs3C69hw/DIdX7KHrtwhEDURgLBiecIuAYENBBpIfg9k6wJyrvIZA@xOJ0keznARQYkH5CiR@JdsY7fPsA2TF6kZdVAxBbpXusGqCjR7tYuw7O8IUrASzEtSNDAxnj9AHvt1sPnzpw9@BFXxx/Nw9ORacotHHIs3FBY1jnWJKM/KRvCQ45ZchmM8HGPvihaU8svynPGs6O2TDqmToy/ZMTq6m0E@rKw3u/4P2ek58n33/P/6DdTR5OvJOUia8@3wRGqrFHskCOzNQkBeKh3UkPJyboCOkhNfFeefA9DIIwqD9TosVsw2vXDWqupIAWvCdseP2rOyXws/LgL9wpPiB56j@6Ta38XIrxL@ArpVi/7H9KsXY9oEwztfIpJ9wpfPHW045PGozaPu5kJwpnGXvk1OqOe0gBP2TI6PMVoDJAp3En@3wPXihchsTXGU/k77/nfPLZ4kQOBLwY6ofwp8KdCYEHXwrfH3u408Wn1d0U8h974JqCYmQvEA/5bF4/r2kH@k6Ax1abbki3aFxg8hZA3iSVOrr9dHR7lPr4cXW3CEwe/Bb7j5mNNGDiF5j4ky2fP8/RrRe9YAlZ3/K4vpOOvwseGcjll8B@Orr1a1s5LQqPbiFFg6HTpvoZ60tyvJ6zrYklzPZTs04jIueZkAVUcgqgQU4@NfvYYxfypg1ekmxwy9Vak2B2yOHz@vxIUZUARyBwmn3cJ068X3z6RDlF205UUDJWLj2YIeNZJjntTceLbeToWOtZla/p131q2NG56ylfo3ibRzC9DMe2uitRTaTDGTp/h0GwGvjCPJ9YGstynQNlQ7QHwBDtgeECWItgJtl6woZM2YnQWk4DQS6sJ0TrgQx8HI6B9ROot03PBxVikQGdeQ8Zkn@UIroJ5EmCEJJOSXkQgK5CfYBKYBpwHaQHdAaKDH3/PbJvT1Mwp43jsQCDYbiRj8VAryiFwr@BUsCBqRyBjGJ9SAoB2j7gFOzwuVNQ5B9XkO2v7YEMvpHfctsOErdtz1QxrKcVMN@8Fhm4LT58GPlSEZsg@CeWOuSHtOffHdjD/TEYK@Vaq5mvl9MN@IW5RmJzoujx@uzJVyfOafgkuZ6kEPdGnquzQveSBxMG7EYQKbWPT5bto8tWCYVClZwfP2IMrD@wloBgQD1eYxIMcnSTEVT1AT2XxhK9e/Y0PgWUeFKSk64DzpGgmBwyOMubZyg2j1AYeIUHBnP7ucidQ4kngmHYB@kFnLOJyfnL5GmSCX4oAnqhffAecVJx9tmJVwdeZ/YTXyFdGkjkwNmhhWAnPzkjzbSyk/5B4QPz@pzJYYmmkgmGOUaMHwdYJxByAmEnEHECUScQcwJxJ5BwAkk7wDqYWQszzAvD4dgmGN8EE5tgch2MMJvgBkMktAmGN8HIJhjdBDelRdalxRIELzpwuEm6rqDjNDaScNLwM1CKSSKjgIZ9GRkBQkOvICF75FUklJfYjYwnGbugIl3FQKFQbHMP2seBTXksqvwWHX6rZOvOjoSxirLmSURg87oOWim/wCeEgtB5jxH2CacoULuIlwUOjAHBBCslVQD5F7zH1rNS@vJ44xeOMaTY9T1kxyfoQR6WHHZric@e5NC@ZAtbaC8262EztGbMllO9TaRF5fHOSGthjOzEbWP9iBUs5ugbECELArfBrhe@U2ZTn@4tMvx@kTsI9xb5iigLb3RfLswbD0GecrKS8Z9gSznlWXaKQFobzAD7ZHMiAy8aFD80l/rCHrt@@@tf/R/ot7/@079Cv/mLv/r//vP/jMP/Cf/8n2CzoNAa4E/@FP/8O/zzr/HPX@CfP9vKRODDx67f/Oov4fZ/@g/oN3/wp1bSv/prlz@yRgQpOGqT88//Gf75Q/zzf7n80TXgn/@xBYizuPzP1I5p5QGoP/mvCEFpGMsa2a/@BiGXDwwMjy15d1Yff9h6xMZCsGbDHQk9vEy3fvmhjtnOeH0uwGvfsZs7H24A7xZyncNHdW/6Hpgzlmsn1tI8xw/xYxR2lGpg@4fHJoxqBAcgb/M@GD32@oIbav8/omPk9mEYiCbPCqYsHW7X3663a5OKYX0uGqjDp1/aqHDYu6YEprcUyDeZCSyNIJ62kBkpa8mIzd8KfhWAM4C4HMmSTA/rpeyynNww6UH2icrwv5nqYqHFw5D1rB052ZyynwhgtwrcUTcvmg1KeRkDU8bN0zfbWUmEMNGgSSDbmt@YsfiGcMH/Et2m5exuk68WXnQY/OmBiTne1kjrglLI5foKLOa0De/FFld4F96i1wa4Y47DDzvP8uwDdt3c3LiorTgGy5De9xAMW5WyVMY6id1NCm0lhbaSgGYLJ9E10VDoBQ1k4MB6cfe5NSvblorazbYRLtxznHbAZMBc0FpS9Ivy1BimXqMmGnlX2b1GvoWSfUjZ/eReITrnDLm8rzIAzt08qZdtuR818wrmdUPtz4m5vROz01pvY9rJs9UpCPeol1xatxyb3NdyuwW@g5p98H1jQSHmH1lQ4BsLikW/XtDLZsV5d9C/zd@vqx1HTaw1/AaZ1fEPdgYoPDT@CkRvo44wxToJerww5UnbU57eXEWePUdnQzztnCmyc162vnXSCJ7EVFRTsJYHPmsqTDlUbAVvvW9j38tx7NdbDBRVF4ztZ/Qk63kHxY2fEuXVgQKjmh@fbSLZh8HjPWfrPIDdcWU9stlWaNZ6hQdGbTEKW56Pj5IimY@PYHzKonfDQHwb5LETupvC7/6A0FZ@z9q0rWoeFZ/RZHq/jpPYu1a2psSPPVXNTnRDIWkEEzpekGHyhYYcP8ZvsSEswVUkT8xhi7RneryYiUN1og4ERcUPyOLcL9AXN7gxQZymEVr8iPMjfosiexLt4f2c18569YuzoquQh/Ou84d2Eewww4/0lzzGnNX3FPf4ZnFWNqe8xi@nt7FNb@N9ekVJN8yXNJNIvNqDr7@s6LBngwEAN2SEv06G334m/hU5O6Sso/GR9FaGbyaxLxg8DH@Y0jSApm3woAjy4V/fGXC3Jrz9Fv/fb0Ane/5bm48Ys40l6JtJHtt@ZIpmkBNBFF7wAHjRi3XP6@LWop37xrLsiQ6Z4fmRiyguBT/LAB1T0wTFWG/1Ooi/IvPYGeaV3BMPmZSVuIcmfeZH49DbTZR77AsytxT6HhvSv4XXqXFd4PpEX31bxbGiI0pPtd5D4GH87I4pRp45I0DHb4gM5595vW@LlQUiraWHbMYRCotv848s3L1UzXgRNGXtgag6aNADctgEOeJDW2pL6zlV2Xr9ka1HrfHHaskKfnz3qwwBPlgvt2H9m2K976nPumddpW8YEdawwd0q40fRHIz4YbDXbfjLWPT1mpJVhnWmlNPKO9bJWy0uvdfiW1LhyKRllXybSH5N6L5Z5rZEzUK2UWHZXzaEvMKc5WSZ5z3bGK2Yd1tMVV7pBByHW0xV3hhVHvco1HVOoulMfMZ0yrIvvJQEwSJcZ3BtwxUjhDnooyVQTt2wXesseZGUCadtWS12zB2PbdEtLnq39xG3oCgnjBdyn9dl8m@Wyb8qk98pc90DdovcAqL4nSLtVsDN814TyIJovqGdcRKeucPlPbUNH0XldLz3@sUtuY8lP3LP3MegkN2C@zjvAaXs7ruPcyRguI8bJDB2H19BYNO33D@5j51ugQF0uCWBzzjeVuH4nncfZz3eZ4q89M4pN@g@XrcpwHyybglHnq3l1Z6966@uV1UFwW8ZlX6EJcaAi4qrdffgJ18G/gmofYITJH5ModARAcYTkJ1BY2vEsMqBYSNI3qrl2Td8HDtLU/b6xmYNBdJ9qa1FFSwlU6KP3AfuXWVkEYZTyeIjXIFArDeP91OE2Fczs6@RY5cOEkoaebd8wr0gsQf6HpJ@B8DbizjyJr/TXrsorAb8Njpx5rfofEWOUxyhCDsDePeQhZn6o/udSuG2fnEakNX62y30eo0AN2LAAbFaiaDd0ulgw2HblBSmqdqukJBUvNsnbefBH7tTYul9kY1oBbtnvpFMou2aYcWw3fm971VnKx8mbUcF4cQ75sHqZetxgehinLTRdVuWqtX5gIQtndMnD/ILWGxzdpDAWerGT8aKt4YhJ69VJNFcu2oSMgfxk1FTzrRK3@zL4Oelftn01ckJJjjQiBFs5VyXYulX9RfY76plvzsGtcOEFwXsM6z3D6Wvzet3R9kXlMubYl83IE70o5x3r3G0LmHDcpgdbFnm78naKxMfv3bEMvKtQtfYX1j7DtvWc4Kv8O3l3MLCha0EfbYbOcYLs@PQ24x6bZHIs6BjtARxSTYeq@JrSjdVe59Wq@L7mhin4DEaLr@4gfXdBt5uPIyPVEB/wXKrl@PXtJF9inXfxmvqWzsX1q6Dir3E1mdbbUWCuif@a2sXLYioPtZz1UqpC4NuPB73vt6KwL0W8m7GcerdbYL1tCXkxweZkJfHYt@JoaqbH@8V12uXMhIBxgBH9m0s8bP7uNfWZVv6/EXfhXwW7BZHbVzjTTfgdrQSNnU4PGRLNl@tY289R5yNxDFvgd9@MlvDu0ZYOvCGzuMjGb4eH7FzzuOjPYrhpllvI/3uwH7rTWjrDbAHu95Mb7x9Gy8ATCfW@0ftBTj7HADLD@UAv@t3/e7uda6pYkqOswNeH8JbVGvPCE@Y9VqvCHZirDf5gqR6QhE8hQ1F8YOmVi4MjRc@iWulXc5Hy9DBh1wamqrYr/odW6@DJkduGs7SKyF7qsw54gZilUKej92iyHLIcvbFyNs7yUHD1qtSOcVaQnZ440fCIEh2fEJJmHKMJc0652rt@mF4SSZCMPHRAh73ZGGC36AJsrtnNbksQasMC9JgAIJE22c5Ww4uTfxSzYAqBrKb96G3yXtQ7fMBbZ8wcjanvQ4M7PTsHMBhoFAMrKmkHzi7@QJjsZsMwodsMMRJi0DBNw6XuBVM@LfyfvQsvbtX1vl4Mb6PnkfcstazdZKOz22eccoWn@1H7raWpu1NS6IHtnYunbNkKPvsnxTZpwxiHzXN4zpwOSfs4KDlNsHJvHM0hQcfinJMfVCI4sEeYIi3fGvAwFWw0Ua217xrl1QFfYfCIfISOiiPWKmkWMBh7eztYIc0yIqJtbz7bAXj@q7v@g5vJlIfDrAutGQN53dEGYfJSYEbWUYfbXTWhgruylYXcG6iWzdhmGp82FPwR4/LB1h8Lq9rBxPA27sfHyzN@zorKEXv7@hmP9YpqOl0ujlh9fp5epAeputduM8wJV9nFMnTdP5C7qdzxd7yXI03Z2KIaXavM72wrxbvLzTpYpK90PKUFOlOfLfhRfIisopmw9k0z9yI5yUxEs/eiDeGkJaFJD0bja/7Ql3rsbohXVXKlfqKLrSu24PrkXjb6YziSoPS6reZwfVCuE50lFm7lSwa10I7WzHHlZE5ZZfVeCfWmitGpt3MDC@Xxfl4UYypXSmavRbibVG7mPPLqMZftKjbWXMYa1wsx0l20l@ms0a/G/f56G42M0hc8P1b8bKRveoP9GgvOm4kufBscilqy@HVhfJUGmUbM96njQrF2IxSasXZXIh0xj35Qrmtt9u9XKY2H7PGrdYfRTrlqdlL6LFweJoWhqNItDg19UQpk76Km7l0sV2Qb9rm7bKdqFHmhdmMty75pOybVU0@PM21aINpLy6lq8Y8dhFqqhfKpVwc1cbn0/OarE3HuYhUbU4i@uCm0FNDoYvrxuyiW6L0yGWnm6iPQokcv@Dpq6iqTsLNZKWklxfTzFNV6GT5RkboxZhM9CbPjsrVJV@dler1Tk3rtCZx44qVbwvMiKre8I10ZlwoTRJss7IsJs6LjWk2W1zMeiFxoKan/U64fBOblypCsXNNhy@4qVn2SdmqTI8uL41lu3VVvKkYt9Cty5dSRFwuMu2MLj7lska5XqIr@njYiIyUvtaOS1mVv6wVI2ZxnL6Yd26TxcxYEGu9sTpuduTO1JRyI7pALbPj61ZPmBek1ZzLR0rta3qUr/NmPD0IN@iRKPbGctVYDc5Lq0Fj2hv0k9VzJic8XfUz7Wg9r7HlghGpKEuq28yI0qp@LbLjWvKieNvLp6WyEs3WBK12fjFbhEJdSazNoyt2cTMqRKQFH2FK1cxN2Xd9Gar7Sr5MpqaGqwMqlCucdwbRK59aEFZ0SeSe4lmfPp1GFrkpfmdqqaXI@iQqM4lC0zeMG3onWS7Pe0bxpp7t8PIqcVsej2O3depmVjRUPZS4LKSTdG3M6OfcqFK8jUtKITLPnMv5ZLGzaiXMfGkqJy5Kg9xlXc81J/xNMj9oLJfjQeJSqJXGaUpI5Or1UW/Q7i26DaO2ZMoRftTz5c/zlacB9ON2oxC6bGVig2k93L7KKbNas@BbqTedkpatjNl8LTGNNePhCTVbXCbSDVORtNx5ORm7nkqlfDo3aGVZVRBunvgrdsw1mksmYcT168LNtWb4zGZPjfSGmfDyutyl27eGEb2QqNtFJ1ZMj3X@qr8wL414Uwmp1WuGvRYrLTk660hP3Zo6Sk/oq9bNiu7NV4VFzeTNxliN9uPR8fnCeNJXV/oVleiOOLlVyaqlER@76kqrOB1llWY3K5b57mWISbcGF2WhcDEbrFrCJDS6eJpe8Bxv1NLd3rkcmy00nxhOzEpUs9K5GcSfnpieUOkmpfS4Va8VzVCTo6fdRin6VOoaRoFvFaVMRFKmuUz3fDzJ3i65prFYTZuxniwua3qIyVOLSrfc5kfqwCgYt/xodVO4VcrTUOymOhLjZn/MTiS21BaZeEWr@3K@mnzeGyxj7akw48Ey1K6LGptJj0ZVqspO4rPMMmmYyrlxVellL9NSOl1KhK61UPxinD2/WPSldqtduehzauS2lw3Hqr0BE@pnKvlBLTIZxGuVeKSUpZq95XWd7ecSEjvk5OzochnRkqVQJka35/WL61FzqFTkbLqzEDNhvqnO4x1OVFrCKhany4xvNExeKmkmUotRLTNntkqFedinXBXLodpyyd/0uGmYE5@6ho/vroaralvgVHlYeqqzzfa0lJVGo3YswzeZaqbBTFfGnNNKNSqZqylsrrSYFebDRocxtNyFlugtKv1srSb0tH5YE3vV9EJkZp3O7fV1q6pMbq4nF/V4r7rqc6No2xTrserCpJ7A5GnPSq1Cb5ETDXFUnz0p54vpTZuOtM4npVZ/5hslb7uzsHRTZUqVTFvkpsXrQdxsVRZa@VIWZXoSqg5oat6qrVamkFbzlXm5uxDbq1VayhhP7OKK5krnxdyN6UvmC@lctdngdLlaPS/l0txkXp6XbuI@YdUo96PS@OmWqimKHNJvG3I8w4SNUCuaW2X50TkzPc9MmpfNJKuxrYt2uXzFDmV@wse71VysU@Y76fTl1fJS5Nq1mla7ajWpqk@5ub1t0tWmXEqKpWK9qUaLM73c6cS5uZq@5phiZNKblxaZeXk67UySl76uKXBhdSUIbH0ul2jhAmQnQQnTWS1bqRnL0NNq9DSY5dSbdjKtncfS2aXYnwmzFZPOzXy0UVjM@zFJS4Sa3cW52OXLg8FVPTMMazOtGctGqcukWFbaveywnFwKVxeldmFqCo1@LyL5DEYbNa/TLaPFL6VzPjactYyuDJ1P1KLNTDZpyLe5xJUu@ZgEn6H4Tpmr0aVh9KZy2Vfn2UW5vczBlCPBijUmqi6V9jQxVi6ujMxV5@kqkRi0ehdjKHg6vB3yUsuX6feEa1GuULc3V@1xvjZt06Prm3K81rrwJVZh/fyJV4fnXHLZXFUZRhCTg1lxughrJT5xnriq8vLlolJvicIg1ghdy@fKisop8SGTFtn5bK7QvmU0k8gPxEyroui5Fn8RF9QaR9OLzq1Z7dwkrkLnzDXTmMyZkFGe04zYVaRlt9LthvpUZmZcaZ0GO8v7Lsx0tzGq8@cyXenUiyt1WcqHjFa6khWvpvOlVlpKeviWL51n5RovsWCWRGODpt4arzKzHtURF6VsJhG/DV2ABBmGnJx3I5zAG9pgMaJL5emFvBhNx23dN1nQdd9tdxFNDttDg@ZLpWalOM/rUfXSGClULMaHLjq6FjfqT5NlMWvmhu2WHMkm24Ne9aJLl5viVfI627iNC9EaXXwSkp1GjOFL0Q5Ps3V1MjNhROIHY6q0ZPo6Lws6F59Wn6L56dTXX86mpk@7jZ9fJTqDcZad8ZwvnO6pT9yifSkzUiUuDIxqZz67KXTAQlTas5ZCFW5bWvhKuhAbF@1qeczW0vWVSWeSHf4mMujqrKiIs3rYjF4WhUGcF3P52/Eod1F8KjJd8YmZs7J@fR0uXLBUXPRlTLUv0@1r7VpZhTgh3a0myvP@KjsZVkThohjK6d16rN@44uQ8DKPSU4nR2oXz0m2/Jw9pUVWqjTrDULexUL5zU39iZ/3r2qqpLi70wWW6JodvxKKi1m7abO5apyvxTOE6O6rfZpeJWE2Xe0JzkGgqE995WOW5tFKKUXFhJmTaHbolSGE2vlj1uLFAs7ed8ThxQa9ixopOK8Z8lBiskr3zCdu5rajnzeWYPp8sbmuZG3Yq@Fi2xmvUtbmqRc/PO76r5XmrOJBbRZGnuclyZFxkpsLlvHcdS/sSGtP05fvt4aJUG2idPB3v9RJsIxzuRMynfm1pXFeodq50EY7nluZCzI@nlUXiQkvHGstF6zoSGd@OFtVEI1aPLtiZOs5ntMIgSqs3RlxZNC8GhYyQF8uiUV71@AkVW00rxUIi74sKXLfWvWXEPP3U6MvmcCA2r27CjRjNRy@qtfntbS5NT@LiKF@Uz2FMnHPlxbIx6o5711UjLFFqtesrxlaxVeP2utJXap3L8rA3H8TjNf2iPUpOV12tLtV92qpV7KnnudpEzq1uQOBi9WR01JLzrY50k6szVcqMddJzsMHZTElaDuhilLkSFeZyMTlP3kw6sXF33M7O6t3FeBRrxKPqVFjFzc5TdCq04t3LSYPme9350Bc6p9TGanmTv47opcpcK5k1VbhiEqHS7bg1yU9bvkn2qtAzsx1G64U6pfnUl42CVZAot5OhSu9qlCmOz6@Ni@tQkmoWpOU0MTqPnftqMJhMR0Y10ZZD8ozu0HJ7PhPGE4ar5Li2vui1CqV@pR9K0JpPis/Nq9jTZbd2y5laRKEpYxnrzznfRR4siJzUjTZ8bVNjJjAXYW5m4StlEA4Zyk2jwZtZNT5uhZNCpKC3FbW9UEftkHR9Hh/PeelqRGWEVT8it@qdfmWxmveT40ifa8xa6cKN0glnFW24MHQ2lrwKtbmn2kQPV02tVmrxGeV6wnHi3LeQM7my3phR/UEl3e8UnqbirB2ppiPp5U2fiUxvZyNWWd3ku6FRrZceivN6J7Kqz8OZ/jmr1CeSNtFDNNNsK/lxYtG6EK6oy1VeWA4T15laO9K6GiXHYXkwbtSY5bgqifztrTFli91B6ZrtF6PtzHVyfCEaaSHeSoqXI3pR6VVvY9m@EGEo37A4oUPZEh@@zN/4zEtejj5JK7ZirpKisqy0pF5jMEtrpf6oNa1kLugMG5qdL6qT8EWdDk@5zCSRu9K7ukwJ@Wh60aqWY8bwNm22I2otNEtotzVpcBPq14YcP2FiCdDB5X7vdtlK1zPzUrdy0TDSymAl@PT5lXJeLBQyCnUhdipPxhOnitN0pFUtda@frtP6oBntmUaRXTwJ9HKpVC@zPL/spovGuNK@bCjFODPpZ8rx62G/pLTUmhS@ovhkfHwTp5UGfzllhEgtHSk8tc/5p@IsVlfHisk387esWamDsitGW1WtO5@sskNGXIQj@RujOuhrt9BbRysqNL2od/t1caQs5vVLs30VnjTYcXsuj2MKp/ki@WS1yrGDMJ6ERW9UZaLKVwPzplGZXek0PVzFpoJ2LlxJVCmkDdLFeuwyxJ2fd3PJFjt5KgmhRDkyTc9D1XrZp0QFLVccTGQmO66PhGsJpgydWG10yTQqUmtwO83eJJcNatXtiUnlsjNXr7LjeW48GzVbizBMr5rtkmE06jdmvzgL9S7jcq867Ddzhew1n@U4I15VsvnqWJu2e5P5RSRKjQrhm1E5fikNYuN4UVh2r6Zasna5KmaHFxFfV7lMmF3OlJ@q8uip0jPN3lNcajeuL@lOJs4rzNMybt4MO7RBXSQm@fOIEF8Vh2y8pUxm02m/WlfU4rJ2XQY2x0Ph5nmPTmud65rZ7l8I/M1FCyz9S1UoNm4utcb5zUV/2lcoOQzim6X1q/OSUbjJjW/ZebG@7Emsb1y9mlej8aiY7Plm0UllOM1Fo5345LIyK@Q0PbYog9Yf1Ja1klCvlCl2Uu7mx75LkWUTennVnkXqaeEm1ivPxXkkmksvlGEi0WIW15fn/HWipxXnk9YlO7im57fJsTHhWlw9zatilco8aeFlbmHmmWj@KnZxcy2MYvN@fhoqpueNTjFmJitipxN5mtfnY6FSYMXmYjYP1QrVa1OJRBft69vxFbRClOIHi@t8XChHhD4jrW6zekHtKS0uzdCXdGjeal/71IHyVBF841qoENZieWZR42BmfJuZXvZjvdZI7pxnLpJDqh/h876mESvexp5unsqSfjPyxSegchJifXZdBpOkZ7aakcW1mOyyq3Y20eF6hRWbv6LTkYuLabIYCl2WkqUuZTSiE5CWp3no5jInh65r7WZk6stVcov@sHHbqmfn5cRtl53UOo3ZJZ6MhWlmLlZH9dayUli0JCGWH9fzYobyFa/nRjWpifVcO6/Ttb5YiIzGF@eFc2F6xU8XecXHDIqt5expOhESl2WZE3SlUDeHaT7cTYzDC76opZ@u2tTygstfstlEO6GPJf5yVGkZI2PW0UQpHXmKLnxmfVSTrqK5evNGGbWGlYrOZ8uhuCHkxo1J7LY1WvRmQr5/SYlmcsbLi/NKzFQyy4J00ypfX/YbzJKvJS4rBX3B9OjCU4OZmXQr0ag1B72KLpVGMHD6ui1VTcigUsyhek1x2rDIzNvpq35iYGTPmUTpclFtSRUfc52vj3IhY6b76OGkGsqt1PxlWJzHB/XrqwmjZ2f9oe@qFqdvRxl1XqGiZj/c4Yxxsi6y3W6b1vL1lWGUE62e7@papoV66DaeuVixzV5Y60@H3UR3cj576nbLT7124wKa88YnxBrlJ2pwfXVhxMUkz/ZbmWwprc405lKf1MXIpKR2W6Gu6OsucsX5U@iKKYyKPbZSGa5WGf5S7yiJ3KRXznLLUSvRpsL5KtO/DQvaZSv31C0MpyM@W1rw4Rv1wvDdRCqL6bmeiMfYSHLGGeH2ZNL2JdKy5IuHh8thKJOfxXJ0X693qHzVl@2oKvSC@m2Mq9BGpF@RTaMVbzbyyXq2kL0oXeVvxFKyUeRubnzd62I2n27GLq@G48hVlzUydKY8HDVC1KiUHfdp00xMpYZUMPLnem4xvB1fT6a9eXxWMror5YqbSoMJK3LauFNS4rH0dfspWmXC@TKdv13JSigeXSSpPi/2L2m5Pr7pJKT8Bd2VhzCBzoH8j2/KU50XdWOY7EDNyyslnm1VB239Qh7WgEK5N9V4cZKUxkMhfEvV6UaiEO/IVyJf7dYn8W5PumlehuPidAHz125udSXmaGj1VrcxnDI3sTyYrpHIU7EznFzPKm2jHs21m6VahGo/1XMiW8yXSu1bs89WqsygMDNb8cRFnuUnmXElv8z0MsV5gW91LnwjX6jZ52eFdlrOt/ucsVjeMklGT4sjKjaKlTNijjXn0baoR7KXw2qYk4vqonqZ0Cb12mUoc5m/FtWxzmSu084n1l4mJ1J0ORDT6fN2sZsdUOnrbG4UaosGX1d88yIByxRk7ne/@KgQQdcVAkbNVKmPyBui7WMuTt45eIKcPIEfb985dwI7@2wfJCDaz1cDLVCO39XCTwgfW4WQvc0gPooeby2evNxbDLDOcQLkgs/xQEfk@HlxZyPUpePMazI@Ssp7BJAdT7KDgvfByOPJ3xnH8AUa/A5KYBN5os5DeOP9Km2EI/icD3weI/NwsrXl6WG3qcEEQpNxigj89Lu@w6cqfA8ZyRZwvlrw7tvWZ0528gNxhqaQk0ZcgaCLZLVPxcCYdlFYrYnj12czUORAFmdj7Z2X63A0m2BiSXK@B1L8pn9yl3zwH/EpFxJMiVMmxlSf98cDdTgTkYy0UW/BL1dPCEUjKAxlhb63jnFkYymaHH0ah98ESjL2yVDWKYrkJGd8PhY5aBAf2uhGKLA@Xeoj8pKAH/8cu05eSSk6mjhSaB3yMbmLPaSUFHMyuVMeThSfz2v6UqaP9XlwxPes90Sb2p6Id@YDeWqfPkJl59F6fPQ89v1VRVRTFX6oug1EXs@6/cwJOQfM6UATTtvuTzOBN1V9O0bE8sRNdjri6yi8S8y9yCmpDpy51AS8dbc@lUDGL7bGPx@mscjJ63Rcww8f8BEaJ7bvxHYFvlDatCdL/DH1gfATb4Hjx@mPj@1DYXiE5fbDBxInWZEWLUgyPDj5xEnlVW1pZ5YskEenLqdbKM88eG/V6/8WSAeqBzL5iF8UpAOYBWKxdwccAWqyNeq1qMLhkqCs90HxOT7eE3zKCfropDkn/mB4LDfk3J1HE0nklB64nCIblJyBgbz2iRMk9k7CD70RV4Izt5X0YTSdaGT/OWjRa3MEv9vwUeMkfZ0zaEzxe2Q9iMXMkByicQvgwDM@im3GmcJ20zhtgR3fyMNXuD4YX428ygII5jldX2LdiB8@wPj6KsnzwXp5pgeZquVYaZFh5yXV8NpNDYzDBxO7NfcxIn5wJxBFtkRPtlJHkIrr@kbyBJInnDl8I3mIcU@Nt5J1SMav1HwjWYJk65nI/ekqpFs7/W8AmNjLE8T10VQfTU6SPdaBHvgokGdLYXuQz@cwdi0CyGoYqz128yP7aBT00WodS9h2xAv6JxErCwCLtMfuPPh@Iy0kFZ/b7LHkYqtMiyfoC/pqYbZzJLD4kZQEaheX7z3awY@2CID@B6oUvU53Crdae13RHfkJwrAzwK0NzAqjn356jzJbEHflj31wpM9qIeyHu1VDi1sbPNYb/zbtamVa2Zn257GPjtnWbo6PxKYeTqcMbVSI1bc2/VqUlD6UAYg/bkdjlycv@rSJuTMe0PFae2z4aHWLr/Mx9Ep6sEcU6ZF@1NsE@W/nKoflHnJyMCL3NsoCnxPGnbxip7GGDuxCnwH0mpsv5IzfkRm7l/7Syn5bbQ6APtKpCW9OLEXLg2l4ZhO4hzzOatdtnWAhO3QfW/H4TYbSLjLpDWTWeXqPgMA8BRrwyOaocWdMlJSg9Uwq6HkmFPETF3ML5HnDJkdZfQuf/gk6F2acPWRP8cuddlUS2sOaV@DremN@nb3sci@qZ2n6/ZW7sx5qdn9yYxrRa3kiUvcJRsljxKD1wU0n6Pnreugfxpkvm@bbsXcMz9u6wml0RxK/RQSf32D0V4VstwqhB7TDcUwC0QxfGZLIIYT7B6WNa/2jE@O4XVp9@00LDFN1spuOabYQOglgKG/n8ts219lGddqnLz6ajnHj31hh@J2KllSAyX5CbatzPJ0rkMF7O3Z9dBThyHYKfpIdW5i6Q5kkOrYtmMFOviD/iJvZYjLmJ/Tpgar2PY7BZBsMBINzQgcA@a3jrNZmlWVeboqH4myjFw3sUz6ccfcEYj7aUWRcgQhsfNqyiYk4GpBuc4K7zZZ9IxnklZ8kHY9GUJTz9AF2VrS0Dzp@GY@h1ybQh72ZHI2PzyQjJ1faep6MxDvqwZXlFOwYipvDmlqfunD8uiEwzBlMtDfnW5I2eN6zymCd4Wmfbvlle@oinUhBbBOvG93xgvSerKk5PXXhYtYC//y7g4/01NDpnqTQgjIDo7q3pA6QoFhvujrGr0MPJLCjMH6bua1NiF82cUIEMYGWwqUFFWHusd94jk8RdXkp60w64rTIUvgIYOI3LguzPlj91oktmmosyO8SJgtMcKqZKkmxCyJn16GfpJ8256ky5Ckie8Zgk3NK8GxgPPj5Ait2aflKBljLQGLx@cbeLRR3OCdRuK57lwu3HybU9ie9e6CMoMDxQ0wElr2frOkUNBeR5Gfq/y/uypoaR5LwM/oVhTtg7cYnQ@9MNMcgbBkU4WskGXD0sISxBSjaV1h2G8cMv303v6wqHcZN98Y@7Ist1ZHHV3epKjPURQ9ba4ACl1focSStTMz47ChY8OwkXPM7qY/3Ch5kCB9xRb1X6xSDDwQjZjSdzlDJcRQU@U8IAAn8juvVLMcpKj8l8sQ6TrnLc8y4IsgG69gHQXSMF6fVYS5QFsoOlAVtye80Js79L2MEtgomNIUV4JRYwR6h1KBQ4bc3akTpczI5Q8LXndRbCCzLyqrHjOZRwC7Olk1kK@hsOnECip0fotEfDGAIoumPpyRx1R@NSGiJxU4MBx6BiOZ/EPEPv4DnXSS8jC@8iS@k4osyXgoVpyoOnudxos/JRJkPf8XpXkUmTpZ/w@tUkNJ2i61LFafzhNzH76UNi7RIC@LEZ1FRyloZRZykIgqJmH9tKX0Zs5vKE1XwKP6LjFf1@1CVfCRlKu15mj/@DVVAPttgUFcWN2ppcRKMfpfbj1EM97ACZpVkdpQ3VzvZKNWGiOpOCtRNUCXmZnt2GlM5qOgeh9tM5uzkPFNUW1K/ZzfFkA623jSsLW0kgRLzPGDgXngkIT4cvZsgwTRR0YRuuWc681plXifIItWuZmtoS6HpBk6qbTbxUxzr/hs/urGnhdPpPmyP3JGSv0jl5U2LNEDc6e5mtsOU7k0W86UvA5VS74wiMe/1JsXtnURrihXo4Bk9RcTTl/dBHqfLyXA36ieSHYXuKd7gHsUopOMEFV19v1eEiHw1/l36aFz2xzQrHPkvwsScus/W8I3UZZuFHy5CagM@KTgX4XI2GwXKrptY8XUOqWfl8BMuI8QUE5OGomHjgqhMn8eTuhxDmYqiDcor3DOMI8Ll05P0LS/gvJa61seASC6KhjlZS7f3MIN2KK@8@GIJO67ogEe07EsIIUtOth7eecAsrWjoi0VS1UfZvicLmgKR4lO2eQhTq58N449lMPhavRSH5fKvlfIvlQRkequ6XPzlSNiJKZKOOCxXyuVPlSPDqE5na3m1MTvIgdZRAQTzooGB/prqpv8NzmUNk0YMThjS1D/059/8YdEwHH/Ie8APS0YEVXkZ@tKKMtt5RQjNrWDvnqa74zAvaNn1jO4F/xifpe3aARvWyBu4QzTz5@NgIW8aTb8FQwCo7009Tkej6Yo3onFlSeKBTGN/QaB8zIm0SGyXVsnCcxc2F0towK8CG/B7mH5jO9IKBpqnBjC/zxeADBhRBIUkM@lAOyEJ8RuM@sEY1WmLALCyFCOgBSDVhsuB/64MBgvxX8oglGLD6WAJy7x9XTIl6v2m3FaoufvzgHrfGGAuFc6WkJ0K2LuyXeG2696N6ViCnjtO@9quWTVx0RPelSWq7U6PHVWJq3aDehdXmK0ahbY8x77oem0KyJgu5cxwhGG2esK67TiW64q2I@xmp2ETNSLvmC3Ptty8sFvVRpcG68u8IAqi1fZEw27aHiXz2nnmqrMZcT7Rroum5VSv6NW8sBu212OOddtrgVmduJmiYzqeXe02TEd0uk6n7VoCihk12602TLtp1YrEn3gK69pqecK9MhuNDUXbNy3LgfApLS8sktK8aFjMifWs2Y5V9aBQ/FQl8EjARl64Hatq48G6tUgd0@nlFVHX@qNLiShS1MymeUnKGdkfoELlUu06VhNCExJu98L1bK/rWeKy3a4x1q7lXNtVyz0WRqPtMmBd18oLOFdk1kSD0KJ4er7oujbjZrc8GjO6Hc9ut3JUyDcEDElpUtYaA9xuSW0JpLbTA1XgwAWQFzdXFoU7wJTRMoGCS6hVvWQyYkggekk1Rcu6bNiXVqtqIboNMje2a@WowGwXCYgm@N6YxLTLWqOcSC75SJXV0DU3z8Up7Lowa9c2JFepqQa4tqotDFv1SmFObblkbP3k9u4HvLdf@dRWyPtG4qvtmkUzPumdJROHd2nQ@S398S4VRwNNFEmv6isoj1X3Q/9h@XQfTB6nWJpH2eQX7HH4lId3ohxcW/5pvONcV30o5wwfPtzfX5v3tM517@9z@Z/JmRLjRzmUFdb3UuWUjqNpf8jL/NTeUhKos31l6z0vDS8n91r2o82HnCiVhr7KhsuLIKy3iZRTAiI2RM/Itxr7E5FgyZ@Y03tF7DFjc7NIf96chvQz@Tt@kWNDIoA6Z3luoVTCGpbFgOcTEclPTNgpiPIMwucAgkdmWQx9/@tTtpxkhyW/2qDK6TycdkHLwKds7gfZH/ynjeyFzfwsLO6a8mRFm4PXZtpRMaf8piATqlyKc9YsK7f2@C@npWFGNCnMSVZ8kVWdPsnuy@ywLyr3CnPHkSlxdgfSNG/tGyzmyodHxxvhV1G4bFu4dQ7fNjTefeF8d/x3dScTUAMLsPwiSIK1/KRaKiXy0KyM55NRYtiqf0aiVTCkMRVD9bPPwzos5Etzwcn8NBjPg5ek9NQNXzpm86Jbr1PPCWmPfvv06z@PDWVxf764zcv/HvjAtyOjS7PoVUDTNI5KtJIqzXvqb5zlJLz7oPSQEG4VdaFxYJ@mtJHlTDlHkP415DYQ1A3hYWACJxsZOAmYZwTu5/u7hq6vW1umqgDZlKo5aDPuv/AMv09TJa4DA2klc7TmUnvBD2hHzV838UghVYFUFfPHs8Waai4tLrjfy9S1wQFe2/C1YiQpZnQ9nvX1GSQJDPpMtsKAO/j8pup2ohRpXouCRnvlYuecJMTuphTaSQu7XCIWnWmoW7AMDCjkVtU3euwp50CIgqsHc@ESjPUoZ0E775F7zqphKMp3Z6dURPv7EacTgY3UnBJK7v@nXcckWwOLIg80iA3C@uRRhHMUw5vQ5//Iib9kTYVVb9A5VjVWvVPN3aaOonKsTaKrd@1BRkhasUMZDlpFPAydpKeTRHCmYPqf8GD6/0dMttA/oQUnUY/R4n44mCz9n0SSqUqsaPXKoAQrfWIscUwtRjMZ1IvJvCYL5jlSTB3De5EflggCVTprHdCTLsWyWwBAJce@RrL9woAvN@LnPq2czrnt7sgv/fPJYDzLaodceqh4Q/cuz3OuvD4ih5ec/IRfFgl2DfhXOWc7j9xnYMFFvdjDWuyFGUnjoMJ9DpQufeRNj6iVc9UEDBXdwuPqVFZNSzf@F3XCKB5lhjr2laai33f2FX0OgU@hVIevv4DoDoTPPiUVVrARzzMIulVvWHrhXX6hRnE4i6QukMdl4bF5jrD/yGtmDEXKlgaMdoAl6OwNlc@mB3@xwnAxktTZhkhMTWT32IwJmKi9yGgaoTvfXJFQ50F2FUnP25Sor5H03cnXCTwK@3KLS6copjxAJU2wFkWzz86gRj@ndyZmfgBYz9L87QnbVRnI75XYmuOVO3HBSn8vjBGhGecKs0sah2KU@oOvCMzoOhqsCsEL/TGvgtJc@zSiNQN7rNs26X/97oIAdWXjDKzI/DmJNpE@y4HsdE9PX/Ak22701MOT2mc@JaVIOArBgVk1DYLImDfhkObb1sby/Qc)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- LNUSP (135) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/lnusp)

### Explanation

To compile LNUSP interpreter either use gcc or replace `v.d = (v.d - 1) % 8;` with `v.d = (v.d + 7) % 8;` in `l45()`.

This is the code this answer is based on, it is derived from [hello world](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hello_world_program_in_esoteric_languages#LNUSP):

```
001 . !.!                  .OUTPUT          .EXIT
001  .   !                 .                .
001 ! .  !                 .                .
001 .  !!                  .                .
001 *                      .                .
053 + 5                    .                .
001 *                      .                .  
051 + 3                    .                .
001 *                      .                .
049 + 1                    .                .
001 *                      .                !
001 .                      .               .
001 .                      .              .
001 .                      .             .
001 .                      .            .
001 ! A                    .           .
001  .                     .          .
001   .                    .         .
001    .                   .        .
001     .                @ .       .
001      .                +.      .
001       .                !     .
001        .               .    .
001         .           ?.....?@
001          .         ?   .   ?
001           .        .   .   *
001            .       ?   .   ?
001             !.......?..@..?
```

When IP reaches `!` tagged A we have this memory layout (interpreter uses 1-based coordinates):

```
  1
1 0
2 53
3 51
4 49
5 0   <- data ptr (1,5)
```

Lowest `@` first sends IP to output zero byte, which is prevented by `@+!` diagonal. IP then enters the loop of `?`s, shifting data ptr up with `*`
on each iteration and printing each letter. But when data ptr reaches (1,1) IP is no longer rotated by `?` above `*` and hits rightmost `@`.

This is golfed version of the above code which is used in the polyglot:

```
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
```

`0`s are removed for Whirl. Second `1` on the first line is for Whirl, `x`s are for SILOS.

This is partially unwrapped version of the code used in the polyglot:

```
001 . ! !                  .OUTPUT          .EXIT
001 !.   !                 .                .
001 ! .  !                 .                .
001 .  !!                  .                .
001 *                      .                .
053 +                      .                .
001 *                      .                .
051 +                      .                .
001 *                      .                .
034 +                      .                .
001 +                    ? . ?@             !
001 +                    ? . ?@            .!
001 +                    ? . ?@           . !
001 +                    ? . ?@          .  !
001 +                    ? . ?@         .   !
001 +                    ? . ?@        .    !
001 +                    ? . ?@       .     !
001 +                    ? . ?@      .      !
001 +                    ? . ?@     .       !
001 +                    ? . ?@    .        !
001 +                    ? . ?@   .         !
001 +                    ? . ?@  .          !
001 +                    ? . ?@ .           !
001 +                    ? . ?@.            !
001 +                    ?...?@             !
001 *                   ?@ .  ?
001 !                   . +.  *
001  .                  ?  !  ?
001   !..................?.@.?
```

First `!` on the second line is not executed. Only lowest `?   ?@` is executed. Only highest `!` on EXIT column is executed.

#### TRANSCRIPT

TRANSCRIPT is inside `/* */` comment for Haskell, so it does not need to be enclosed in `{- -}`.

TRANSCRIPT code is now this:

```
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
```

`<<` for Flaks, `11` for Whirl.

#### Others

`6` in `//"16` is for Incident.
There are 2 blank lines above C++ code, but Retina hangs if they are removed.
Recent update broke 05AB1E, and it seems it can't be fixed easily, so I tested it locally with older version. Run it with `< nul`(win) or `< /dev/null`(linux).

Comment: I believe the hang your getting for Retina is to do with Nhohnhehr. It matters whether the Nhohnhehr starts on an even or odd line for Retina. I don't kknow why it matters, but it does. I actually got rid of the top blank line line in my answer but forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 5):

## 136. [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/node/Wierd.html), 6112 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@xxxx h#115 o# doxe b xx-----
#c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111TaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRc
#~==++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++x+++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOxx4O6O@MoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                      (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (          )>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉
1  1  ! !           x
2   !    !          xx
1      !!           x x
1  x*               x x
53  +               x  xx
1  x*                x   xx
51  +          xxxxxxxx    xx
1  x*          x             x
34  +          x             x
15  +          x         ?   ?@             !
1   *          x        ?@    ?
1   !          x          +   *
1              x        ?  !  ?
1     !        x         ? @ ?
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  x            x
             xxxxx
            x  x  x
            x  x  x
           x    xx
x          x
x         x
x         x
x        x
         x  x  xxxxx
        x   x x   x
        x   xx  xx
       x    x  x
       x       x
      x       x
      x   x   x
     x   xx  x
     x  x x  x
    x   x  xx
    x    x
  xx     x
 x      x
xxxxxxxx


7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pRcxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _     @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._ #]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002429 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6245 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1bb@vMlhj4vIn5B3mpLft8kqwLSd1lW95bV1u2LMm6Wr58/iiKlChRJE1SEqX9@aDnJUl3gplMp9PodJI@3ZkMpoHJQ5DBAAkSYIDJa37FeW0M5vyDM6uKpC62vPf@ulu2xGLVqlWrVq1atapqsdjnjNHvf3@AP6iuysuhrJrIFAwTDXRpLuhhlFuiz5xkxCNRisJQWX04mwqKaRxTB4hFSFJ4aQD3yFQngiKtBB3iIwhpujrUuSkyR5yJBIPnNMFA6szUZiZSxf3ZoggVp@pYCuGcU0kZApgp6JoumCQ9hlBbkblpf8C9Som/KlDTId1ABUH@efqziXh1OuWUgQGQCYQKtVyxkn2FIYnQtaobAsbDC4ah4sgUQlZR4F@BpgGU0yW1kq2ev0piGXQOpHOaLFiI6xumzvGmpCo27@q6OpjxuF7mSICcmBeiJAsGxQPNZ0hzWiCMA@gA6QI3sMEoUdURzoKmExlJiNc01Je5UZhHsgSwJSaFBMw6tIJ0eWQgS5sCBkOdCtskGkgRhAEyNIGXRIknpSPBMgXFACqNMJL4CVpIsowGggwZNiTxQUCGZsZWlE1AmBqoFIIPr72qwPruUAAYRXCZIGjAPcwEFTMbOOLyYqFzmgZEAiObQLgpTUFmJNNrIIEzJCyVkMUQlAHhn7aWVxVxynYt0VziEAf0znSC2xB03AhhgheNBF0AlNxaYnwLXTKBBZi9WVQXOB21dEHw78ruTpFQmIpLMHFFwqT5Tk@9xVrJC81o5whzmkkd6NHWzSXFoXAGHT6dwDfj8ZxQxWoBfTl8wGFbVKGpNd3H@VHm18igHx4E@Fpsnx7qLxRgpYArMqJVzaS5kAYEhkwgkOZwEIdC80hYk7cKRqev2mJLuGyoAbQGKiuoEyQ142e6jrvjhqncBCotq8oQ@AmV1WcK5oeCEgw0Aa9CbwoiYQ5cUxW7jdQF4XBrJEGjGbhJtjqArVQIQ0GtgOw5HHXLNVR5RuAgp2FiAQSuQFaMsSyiDhI5ScZZIB2jsqnWBWMmmzjPTBnglgelIQzCyCWDVwcYaKrOoTgOkJII6EvTrR5IiAJgaAiVVBUn/faf/avBcAh4sjyv6gNHXDtooPJE/XGEWNApCAusqnAyIQvggrh0OzsUMOdkacCZuHhl6RRBiCClLtSZPEAqFKgvJOhaI24O3VEUBd4UbCG3NWYQTbmJrTckW3Kh4lOuDw1LCiBlk2qH0Oc8tBIvUAdEZkLTmSmmUEgrIq9B/@j7dOz79PFBAOL8Yf/RIU0PT0DgwkckCu68X5OcTnZLo4FyMTlDlQaUtjRHqhJBIR55@IyqCYrPu4PDG/Tqfa8/jPWZz38iZfiwKCkDnxdkPAflev0nfIa/l44fT17l3i4RsCwwFtxbBR/v91CgcUifmNNTTlLC2hJ1Qk5oK001njDHcXJ4Kxrz5XXc3I44IAMGFksVyweoobAhC4LmY8KsH2sJDLe32jhhX0Vf4XAqfCw9BrwH3sB21QkGqOlORXFfbUkq1lqyNpqBjgamKIYG2lvHostzIDwGVuImjNpB1CdiTTQ/KBaiEheCVxdQH/SoK0akR9o9DucPYT3pYNj0IBdut0MLg63@DLoAurRpvFHKsrqAggltePgCDaLgwrkhNBFktiuUtStkl0hidqs2UUCvYGx9AaVCfQn6Au51oNod0d@qI4BHIzYMYLP7ypYKmnJLwMLbQ@Km3yBJhC41BS2hLxEvYNUDOkiwxxVcyIx0QwPsFWy5MKFIPL7b1d70NFOns6E70NUr@qsdClc@u2MlwAAkCgskc8pwxg2xyaRAFo7nBc109BXUxDBBI70edkhkyBlDw8aIOvz8umwyljij61YZWNfbreeMiBxWMo7RFJJBpyLOMfvQQNJBO8nL16UDwPxV4Z6fMMgOAT953iHBNQRAyARL4GcmKDcQ5MVI4kcgu5g6xVaP9lj0uniI2i4dFHxIXBeNiWHPfohQYXodhcl4F0UIt@hbPDDGYlRnOxGk8bcjvo6ZM6Z7EKtrEmE82IoN01wYZO8bOKeqou5BCoxco8Uguyl2O4BB1sTGIIxfrvVFOuvaQlw3EbQZaA/o@SB/I9PUjGMYLiRzNOuHQVLolr4smzUFCwtt6kvJVO1wX1b7oJ4N6J@0WwLNz/qS9apCJG7dhmODmoMdJhooAwP48wykzucVDVCcJD6PgbeSPESBExT2rwcACVAYGOUTDaKSS6BUmkuF93nCpCuFodN5gsiDO67HDwGca82XvDrFWgh1iX2ADb6cDppLBG3l6H6i@rm9I956DCDmndcbHquS4vvi/fjxo/fYewYa/uPHTxA6xaFPOBSA0CcSCpEQhgvjEMkRJCGcek9y4LhH78u9i9nyP@Jms/DotJI0H3d/fBx9DHL3rHON4KsfVB1oNoAO4Qvg8fozGRz0@z1nC6houC/atW/YnB0QaWgIypASLE3VTVStFYpP9WzrIuOhZ4ZOy1KfVmB8fZpCD4a5jGdPfpiUuNkh2FBVM0MaDMcT6BIAOZM1ylRn0Odh/iFNJbNMZj@yggV702huah7K3SCoS4JJOaPRRtbxRGjTNlAPAl/enhOJujpdaziDEviRijyHUQ@25Xfmo3jYd1JjOHXmzEa34pM4fopnkmGeGvI8Cqn27TrSAUxhQDy7DMNkjhoGAhiSzDbXkQ5kmqDEM86w3ncjv7DMC45fTze3xpFtjPvS389EeLNnfuwUmsAlDtS@IFuJWEiQxbBprcJYLSRilH1BocF7EHvyUtZqXwbKhD4essRXCZxO2RS2YKyqwNQEVSSDLCdsNye17ggPlMfuqNHdUcizSYlsTMb9dq5nGwsRWhCEiYrV4ib0BEZdfAcFTNPf5hQlY0R@dkDfUPQ2heQ2pn2R/OwBOHZsJxB9PJHHLLnE00BsvqkqTPoXBIyMAgQZsEpSOLpBLng82EfP7si2Q0xfEGcwNaT7koLD3wALpVMEUuz3pfdAgS@YdPe6B0yf9fexDYRr9Mb4QTuMN2e6KQsD5/rf/2AADfC2eUbcEqY0/GQdeAK@4aYKie@2lpMV35Cf/S1LYMYzWeIIG0joWyh5Dk87OXkd2I8aq14UCo04HRp36TYuCCf@gWH0K3JmU64L8mwguNf9hRAW75pYdm5FmpIawRXbi2S8fCf7KwPRzo@n7bqscgOCxV5OkYRNa9vtIljcECpHb2kk0ITfQadrx6HN@gkYLObM/sVLJt9qV0nD3/1cOd4VMibO9VkBpptcX3qHj5iMxHuSbXcYbGKERJmb2MEnHNxfWbs6ujQcgmnlXN8DAzsapjoaxwv0glzeVTLKzNDsxsChr@DTZfv3PRB3hXcdeA8QqimTn18ieEQUeOgdmFS8aBnaYpH0iqky119iM2z0yyUIF0hGUlAwGT4QYKJ4UF3PcjfLo5r2fn5sBZD86fT@3PZKKkHAq6IoCN/qtTDySFNODkUGW8F3lbBrtm5Ce0DH3JwDg1bmDBAQ02GzMIdmIT9fE1o8mPAzmdM3oa@I7IYcdzHjvfnwJo8m8aosOZLp3rynDV/PJDZo8Fo5@dlkxXdv@TsA4x0P1KF1aH@HVnkTz0nfkaPvUFD2dBBPuLcEI6y@xzteXeDvu713pM4F@3f/oLXaS9V3qJ@QTCQDJoRvsw/4b4krXtwkP/u5ONlLlcnLe@OP0bWq6iNBMVAkzGATRyEr8jBky7I9P22Va@/LtCHJqoGa5PdrvACj3zDs3/3SvM02iVNC/MjuY@vw/mx7iSIDHMqS33cal5OHqpxIDWkOft6VgJkuYi3vXL9Xw601FMt@U0OtDR5VYZ3ru6p9Av/fEg6y1qrjJYit4FfsqH3qzJm6vl9BmBPgdcX9lSsxKZIzTNsztfcaQOdHC27pXv8Wo8d73HVHD21JzGWw53CGdAoCpm6b0H@b0mJfL23wfTrqDdrktyqx1bgTWQCNTX7fNCmKMOwvzMEyzPdrLFGeCTNhrwap9ccCiM3XdMf3E8U41Th01jZoYB7ehl1DrZzJ4HdRjcdzfPdVhcPJEnTyb1oze1WNBja2hifPdQjUceBtxqEy03Yad4t3jZnS@DrnRprbs9XBDpE45ZdqpNS3baYdM9wQyPc9k704VWHKq07BhlC@o/0dpGQZyP7dQUxiNpjHEl6R0r@K9xit1yrBfgV7BFpVmhghvKz1fYon8t5cnQCn0zAbUwRziX/f4/Y@RdpXVfmXtA7o04GEzTQwPrE/wrda6Y3t4yxbo82qhIFXOPrie@sR9ljjTByBe3iS/G5D16FKJhkcvqeV36zzfWXU2lr1@9b8EUZssuhj6Lwbfo/eBu7cbDgVTn6VYHdFjHYDX0OWDke/xz7SXKOXLKrihVh76XXjUHHwSv9oS@CUNAgZ/EiYCuT2KxY/NxjPDPfyLpCl4u@e5DBNlkXfyadJ0OEV/LuzzLtlEpmqIhi0yelDAc9VZIEDa9SOfU/Juqute5lbnnJDofRNydosOeANTV6XdoL7Fx@O7T0GHrJ9Q43Y00BVmQhLw73uN5aXPLTnbPpVbPs6OY9XNr/Zq8P03hXmb9h8ykgdKSNhpJOesb57r2@ARJq2T9XXKgH0jzhjgndwHYWkmRUUekZbs72Rsc1nWZXl7@EzVo22olTV/cuvRexDNYCsvwjvkutDgnP55kodjOCEXWQof68XjYQZDFSGaqqaECJ3e@mtVNvN@jfGqa4k6IOvwTg7PcQzaL15bAQdlyaIk3THgcVYe4kdlBVeF8hWsru1iA7wBvdsOpM5U9XDiMD5fFwg4PdTdiY89RwqAOZCET8dvHlvuwAZSJYMk8BKIrq/R4dfrGPmmH1BGeQ59qDHRxsr2UYuWhpxsGnYWe8PucfMoTcU8h56H5RjxHgJqCDDTGAvKLcDJ0rkYtO5qTpSuCnxF8Bht6YntlMCTNCx38@IUwaygNowlJFlC1W3t9Zt/40WXqv@b389cNyhQHcZaCoZYPkNFezCp06Fkbr4ZJfrlJ7VNA67U2EcixFejMWlh/JZZCwkE3Q18YJSF6hdaqUcpwrHyRBu6lhjbVFhNyoeRbGrj2k3mk3NQBVssXAKXudyK8Wr8myqoIU0MEdGGGbbCi8Qp431NhuEMJhi6rizDIKojAYCXikcYMLISCGr6oTsH2JK/ttf264kkChhEcJht3jiSbZVIsKjH/Hf4Hl1BlS7SFaCrjogPsxk0FYzbISBUAt2vB/xI474uIAkhlwPD1yM7eWRzzZRqIi82BMS7xufSKLvMNs479wzj5lfoykt/Pc/oP1fHL55fhVKsoYniFyQkxcsV9vJDCRvUr3Ic2h5nGphnzviYrYWKseB1ofDpLlcj40pcdcjcicsiMcG2QhVsDLGfnCKAf0Dbv0Etd1pMoe@mT3ih5omimN3URhEOQjZDn7E8wl7H@Ashxb6GY2wrIR4xMYZuLMZImOHl2km5@70RLc34@iC0J@Rhel5JByJZkh1Dp8yp2ckpAsDFfuf3f/4YEWY0IOVLD7ShsuchwfrV0zkFringh46/IHGHahYLXw5DJ8xP/9swBTc43nxntibk9DLD7/Uy/Vis5VttZvAzRe7sgclVZ9yG02BZUGTOR66j0wc@4AtuiQY39Yeaw2yvgNwnw8dcugUu/76/euENajDak/Ic2gH1yAwKm/n/kb2ffkNYSv9LYCjmUQJOVoU1YkgOTLjNbY1aNCVLdwuuLvPQGe7HMH7zXtUIeGRB2WASyHg0nfyCL2tpd2Cn0gENOO3GfV1HPtQAK82EG8BMJPWZeH62ul25fZW/uXvocYajGt/1xoTHF@tMYb4Wo0BcJON5Chly5V2o7ibCcRp48UN9o6OnfBF0rdsf1BbulTH99DVTDDwjGx3Ik7e6FYDzSVD6ssCkTcRjwxgl5PuSPanDKxdEFZkYZSVDdDkgwGopv7SxJoNVHqY@CTYjgkhBXkOgFnh9UAbRB4KwxqZtz5ooLkWMH3lf7IzHxI4gtmg9vjMPgj0b//Zv7L9ZB9MCP@hExYh/E/t8I80ZtBbXz@bxjVrMFs65ToyYLi0Kz7lrK064RELj4iSMhOQNAUOzglDMLhN7Ka@Gzy@@w7wExoBmIlVL9a2pDxBf/RhT61jmsYGBp5/hsm@tmBBO4CyJo5bzzPstwwDBJ2IJ2IsDUSG5i7CkGQjDGk2Qr//GGSNmkta5qc@j05PT5HH4DlZyCRObEbSh9yPUc9Pa0IPAZaybZF7BHkgyyYHpJ052XyHXID146y4y3lZL3o8ATPDbhcYqXwkACB@HK04/PDAUKg6rIJGVwTLJOp86dpYYOAoxAFHsL3XXUQhQGTjxu61r2V3s12K3Ui2pDm83QyeLgZrYrBjzz7Ruf8RPZgPyqPjZY1AYP5yjyApEP6jPa7Xa@nJvnX69b122cW1QZ@bioq30EtALfJF6EiUZhP@rZ7icVABvbhf/AwooSdAz@IFaaxqRjZfLF/W6s03TqsE0vsazIu8Z6eBh1A4eP@4DnhfSb3L1FyJbl7nSi4rt6narERhiM1y1Gsy95X2mtJ3Su/ae9VvyyYJbwpime9FTCZ8oRJZsX2LfZNKbwHm7b20N6X6/F9e7h9Pzx6UgzfF/7zPn/8gfISFC0IPBvHm96I9Oqfs7sC38MNWRth154p4Nk@rrJ3V7PtN9Ptup@tHtza@p@5eP/Y7jZzRA2FOKzNZpsLveAFA3cO0XRRxvLQJc@kFXeOSymJSNwXy1JvVxG1qkFOXt0@ZOf53aybV7Okp8avnFJiZ6BJvQxtEQduTWOIEDtOYsrmZ@cBsCq8AkQnekkxmQFWsdyYHElkH4XTXMXCd0hSmUqjl0oMVx8aXFBQZ9pEcQd1kqX/CZe4ttPZm@5qbadjQZMn0Yf9OK4wniVAbnx9XgD2VBeweepp@dHxRkesyGiBep/UZ8KuuamgzMS8IbqgBczNUmAFyEAMBXc6mACeSS0PAo4SAqmoIMgMfvS4R91CKz6lDeDqIQ@nhkWANpCGMND5/EFTSr1h246/K@QMwofaCHrZZdY63XLcZ84t8bLc4xt1zYUkZCJYPP09x/Ii5A/HeRXfu9XveyABx9HW8fgevPX5dZcGZTq/deMu@Ugjp9FoR7PaddDo8MijsbQjzCiixaeoVCMIY6hOnnIZ8M@IybaAwIre@B58SNEzdj0JneDxbIAUFAmRGAheSEEYkp0hCkowXDX34QSMfnYF2xrGGMsCXlaShezYcfoQwKcSPDvGaQh7MDTwb91NgcEKWY4IWBmD4O8YULWDuhSmyr4ekWAovCOgAtTeZdOThiHRA4AWpNTr7AW20waYH2lxNp4@d1thVh2kEYnG6R2MA2j1qzrU4gb@OyxhwDSsxgMrDVFMChfL5SlAU6K8@kJkp9E7EzUDIdH/Qfco1uHmAipRwYJN44figAaG7D1YVvV9kFeyZQ/qEzGtPXmDc/@kBD/yiM/Qv6X9Ah@mTL75DObOkwRjzn/kORxk2ED0KBA6VI9@hgs2RH37A0@GXQ7B2nsKesMcCoNCh7D8BeQbrKHOonBxyp77DQSZyRHLAbSDg/wIZfm3Q4S@H3At9@ANYE0GI0e3e6Ts0/Lg7MOEw@wL04R5ySAdBZr74PMhDnlHFxR9KgQCmIXz4hAn4Nf3QDJBx5aFJk5n3iWPk0sOpq0Z2bZV1S7x55tZmoBN9vNboceJLbG81PLnA289V7UnbZx/9/vcHbAImUZ8SUZ/6KRL9eHSADj576COP7vnyUJh77zkxEn5@rE/q9Vv/gw8k0nuQr3nYmAf9iNARTR3QR8zPSZr@6aefwPpE92fhs/Cj/z7kfbz3WWfJ5FEwkToKfvay9iQaJmQs6/dFIn4aPTTRQ5LjjgKxyGflRJIkzRgM4KuO8FN@YIllsJR8gI@PrXu98ai3@SP28v/06SP8kX/4rG/x70cS40QTkLefj37ke7aogzPruz9P8K3lSLBDs2zkQfmAn7hOfPz8AeosBMjn@PgzmcggTzLlUdXPGBqNDlg2jtQDGPosAfWRZYXwhzrgD1aQxB4syd8TDrNsi2txCP/38V/DxH@dCf5r8A2eOvh1JhP4zo@1DoXDT26IOvjp9KfM3@FDprnAO5iIHJydPb68BEL34R9PAicn@Iv/oRO7wRPysUNAxGMgFDi9Pz0Nn51ZZ6HHs3vq4At1YL1QBxEPSNzDEXWQsU4bhNL7wplD87Mzt65A@DT0eF@vgP3cCkZOQweRUjYfjDTbuQMW7uKbW5wYxbeNYrZQawN0vVLMNovn5U6xXYd44/Hp7PPnQBha4nP47BEosX4VOAtkTNNEd09HYfTVz9OekH1LHRTOrDYdOgViK05MgxQTeoC7Bz8U9jN1cH9w7/sU@RRhZGbOsBN2cq3W7H/LitUStc/4plaDZMlixqrOjJgROwD5sBihzSyZpcVM1Ro7gKAAf8wUghIjWsyQURiFZdfovv4/ranXNRVQqZDNtBgTY2VEuA5rtWtAJkLBY/iTGIaxgE6LmcM/IyMirOyPTwyptp95eKDukecnAZRAmPWGGW844fVKj/GE9vzlJZJ4vicmQjz9eC9YkvnoQUHv08N9Op32Pp4c0MbDA23rRU8k5jnBIC8vT0@FbCv79ETjFRPr9DDwORD6DJ/MWeDUuXw6GJxh5oZPPz5QXt@i2@3ib3cxX9ghErDjuuvE7RsSgM/8nby7AWu/OPh89/HHLy9@v//Dg/fEa9fE50MCGL4@D/tgRUQU8fiJRZyG4YSNYqMlEfefnSXicJ9I@UM@hiTbWR48mqY9eMJkhh0mDiiZTFbXuSUBisGI9uDh9KcHz33kMZNJx0l0PJROIFUPpaN@j9//I3t66pQR8UO0x2t5VN2Lvrxs//m@vJz6yMeP//x@HOn8nvl9kOyPw531xWed@k59OA6icK4vL2c4SOC@QOje53/0v7zYcfDr85/aOM/8wDu8jPD3@K8ayNCQ9@DlAFsiCorF/b7@UvDHEr5UIO38ZT5CBXyeqDcK9fJ4Oe/9/eej6FEydv/p8ejxyHd6FD56OHvc0fN@7wECWXZlL8MeYL5RB@GThoeNeLxYFk/wfoAqC2FZHaJo@mRXGLxPvqPXnxSbDhwFPt8fpdN22UdHP3@EbgPooDAPfA5AfpEPnZ6droVqg9J/Bt8vyGEyhF@@gJzZaWDY@JwV/4cHiyH90Y9O@pnDLwfcywnBj1483pMdeSX4fd4TsiXk@eI55PR79tHz4jn80n/BFuAR6yeGRjx2cnIUs8PJFITZI7@9yhln4M4NQ4pgcDzpuScHWJy8wHM/1CrTF4aSAlbfDpMC8XicjsCv9atEMWJRJ3jrxN6n8YQ8dgdCqTTBd4AMI03BJKMPLb9ASQZGUlnmdKSK4kc7HmZLqC8IYLAKsozX/PBkAmxqebCACexH6gAUDRguhgCfaZ0TZoKwmM0WwvqTl4xjbox8Y5gM48/vfvNn/xC@fw3fP7avf/zv03H8@7vf/C//22//4q8g8r/A9z/D9z/97jf/8g/sL7n/r/D9v7fi/qvz3YKzvxTg@ie/@82f/Nvf/eaf/jl8/43z/fPX39/@6X@0//8f5w8H/@q3f/pf8Y9z8w//mPqb//CX@P9P/sPf/Oe/xP//@//6N//hX/zNP/l3JPCv7MD/@2/@vf0Lhf/ZH/32X/5jqNOf4vA/gjD8o0DI/gQcgD/EkT8fMmC0oYeftyF/plkYFRC9FfmH6OcH7M/HbiAB/7/@mWZYiLYh1zi3If/od7/55/8WYn/@jCDOgfzHbnZHaHYgd@iEgv4QIP9iC@APKbA34f8j/G0@FhVByI7ZirYsirVDH3eAEYm3jl6pexwfj4IQv4l3ML3JgZNwWpzdyeUqnQ0N2zl3BxuLisZ2M79KBiNzfzLesfn0eQf6I6nvvrJswE8k/ePewnAZRy6/3uYn2T456R/3UfMZkr9qa1OvKmdRu2U5MLuMfw22J87ls7WN2vpWeAuFg3OnfMsWiB1Au7VJWTtFb8FYr7Dvu99CusZIbQhZ31pr2dsURdnwdtBaV8rlMEUlUbsOP43y@UVr69oqZvMXVALlatXCq0vcAYqjSrHUWt8m7VQ3a3yNolesVF7fOpeeOkM8h9U1ObLAIocKhU9PWZY6axZbENGqITbChKmzW2SFUb1@Y3g8KoVHiY8ongwGw@Ew/OBrkHzINXz4owvCvm/BH1DXeD8jzdruJRLOASFdSOMNdRhcFgrxZ@jjkytm2vuRcMFROKhLw5GJzIW6BjAMA8zKtZn5xujsUhcwmE3xs9r4nBATT6QlETFUGA99kUg6FU@lo5FUMJVOxeJsIh4PspEgm0wl00wQptApNpGKp9lgKpaOxmKxdBD4FU8nqQNBGUgiTcNcivV4EAlICo8fTjzFT3mq4dEZdTAQREkRPiDLN/B/OBi4EWiWQp5o6oFBHpr2sAkKbzgeWRlPJAroUZQBjeqhPCvEowMmn4oyMG/r45tcKplNRD2eJ5ICnzzj8QzwTZJJlXJJj0fAN/EUwyRzHo@Ib0qlPFMqeTw1@wZ/PJ6le8MwUNAI3xUTDHYR90j4Jp@14cb4JpLCRXk8EzvFvpm6N0kAU/BNNIoRII/neY0OI9ftolIkl2nfMEwu7/HM7Fqk4M/jaRF8UfhLQaasnRQjFcyRJAbfejx5@yZG0J27GPBNEd@knJuSnYIBAZ0Md32Z4ycezxCCQx2MGI/HIrEzAUQeQthdUjE5j4eHG37JKZBPHJnCKrvMDnPwyeeehtZwaJ3zOEVqzYY7n2LJSRm/TsEfkjJpzaz9KdPlbOgmWTXno@MUpb98@1nhlOd3U@StlNqyNqi18IekDIduwrC2/pCUvR@cIqoOmL1Cg@fOTyIY654NApJCrrJleU5AqCncvdDS5/9CZqQ@ZEgrAbq/jwnOYBoW/zRLeRJJz/ERXD2fPFEIWj7EeMGw9ngfPB7/ffrxkycZ9xx7P30KeX9gPyFPMu059iSTHuQ/8USgb8Y9ngSKgNDfgS0qDENe9MlzogvmTFdQ5OQFU7DKMCeEEvTsw1cuiH/7/i8OWP/kBa90A5nPvlUgEISv/xOmGOaTMEX2Hy/BgvefvND0KdYcLF4/oSnqDGfK2IvjAAgS6ybZymWtHRBMmsNhBN9QiMLpWsZmhM@T9iGwlkUJfh88ZDJhr1j6vN5kxOv1e08AyUfk2VKp/hNCLLKZ6nM54wFeAGfSMPd1qu9Lh2BmhkJpIP0NSfrk2DA5HS9hkxKPkSeR9uBofGZd2i3sczDEBo@P@vHTs/@BsmcKCZY6eKEG@KHGWBqdpE/wwhJMYU/PnDxXaJkcBi62SD6hDr2YaG90x9Y4IL@H2Ng8CEXVmHpweHhIHZy2zjxRTy38dEo7q1JnNFmOejg7iWXyeGUNbNHww9Ppx8Av/YRx5vDZZ3dN7QyvIL75xGKULmBnqwE@9s5eYUjFMV@HyDgANCeBv80HSqYygJQ6wZNQz4HW4C2Ll5d4BRM92BU9/fUBWYJA9S@u88tMIftzx9d4N8bHHTfJo@f3j8j/66okf0lFQ2dkORuLKIKWfmmmf0z@mPrxul1r10qfmePUcerhwWnOIOtlvaSp7NW0zzCSSY0idWD87Ffj7K@Vy5ODY80bjXnB6H7IHNiVZ5P@g7NIMmxwy4NHx3PUF0tigYV7Mi2NsOhA7O5@Fjs38ylZZYSiUv9gMBxKkX9w/dPPhzTt9cLk4fDs/pfz84kstwIJiV@HTu3/U/hB@ZpNoScR9/ixQ67x49OPTwcI5qbIE4nj3hSgkT373J4r@6wj5ccjBf6EI4P8CQK5VY5OzyDKgAjnXsAQgv@IpumbCFgQ6XQilTigfk/TX9vMhtT17o4oCLoxm@7b3snq0jWHt76U9RYPBK5nK0GHq3uWnWtqIGxr4P1LbGxsxzn2x1YUOQJyN25p0NiFDsdSFA5J5AxRJGIV5cOrLyZxhUJH@ABO7Cnsp75QHwDXjDeJ9x38nFDUB@wGhm99LlwQ/WCYfuwiw/ipDx8cZWuYYcN8wshxJicyxJ5QLxRmDzcYGAjvvBGPF9u9mMNOVapmP78jL5GdySCjiW01Ec9gXO4WwUdItKmA2hwhUiKhHFfOLv6DDdafiZiUUrlShDwog0Syg@vk9uh9fNQSqd5H0e8UjhiIwlgwOOEUAceAgA4ifQS3f4p9mHkfgQwgFqeLZCcYoMCKDBJKgkh0Mt7j20fIjtGLvKwagNgu3WfXAB09OcU6dXDHMFwJYCGuHRkfyECnD/mg03r4TIv7Rz/64npK@nAqOkWRjSungwsawz4llWTkpwNbcMgZVg6bCTb2MQhNe2J73PnWcE7MhlEv1JEZnJ7YTaWdUFc@3v8F7xSe/Hr6ww/8j9r99PHEP82Y@BoITGG4mvgkG@TIzEwzIB7avfR4YoKOkB4zU/@VD9/DSAgj@wsl2sw2/E7doOZKBmjB3gSGP7i6V0K/Vh6DpXslACTPgkd3mVWQyzBBC75Shg3KwecM69QDyjQzq4Bywp3CF29a7kx1YegOcCc7UTjLxCdnVvfcYwb4IUPGQKAElQE6jXs5EHj0Q@EyJL7NeCL/8AMXkM@sEzkU8mOoH6OfSvcmBB4DGXx/7ONOrU@r@xnkP/bBNQPFyH4gHvI5vH5Z0w70nQCP7TbdkG7TaGHyLCBvmskc3X06ujvKfPy4urdC08egzf5jZiMNmHgLE3@y5S3qO7rzo1csISuiPs@vpONfhY8M5AlKYEQd3QW1rZw2hUd3kKLB@OlQ/YL1JTm80d0QxxLmeDjaZ12R03LIkjs5Y9Ig5@qaA@zrDXmzBi9JDrjtpK9JMEXk8GmQQaSoSogjEDjNOUwWJz5Ynz5RbtGO@x2UjJVLH2bJeKpJzhLU8fIsOZjYfhLqW/p1nxp2de563tcs3xURzDGjia3uSlQT6XCGzt9jEKwGvjAvJ7bGsp0uQdkQ7QEwRHtguBDWIphJjp5wIDNOIrSW20CQC@sJ0X7cBx@2ZGD9BOpt0/NBhdhkQGfeQ4YUHGeIbgJ5kiCEpFNSHgSgq1AfoBKYBlwH6RGdgSJDP/yAnNvTDExsk3gswGAYbhxgMdAbSqHw76AUcGAqxyCjWB@SQoC2DzgFuwrvFBT7uxXkePr7IENgHLQd/sPE4d83Uwz7ORfMN79NBm6LDx/GgUzMIQj@ibkO@SHt5fcHznB/DMbKdb3dKjaus034hQlHanNe7fH6ZNM35xlq@JzCvqQQx1iea7BC75IHEwaMRxApdYDPLR6gy3YFRSLVQhA/wA6sP7CXgWBAPV5jEgxyMJgRVvUhvZAmEr17sjk@Y5b44JJz1EPugbOYHDI4y5unbzYP3xh4mQcGc@ep250jr6eCYTjHNIbck6/J6d7kOaQpfpwGeqFzrCNxb3I9NIg/EN6ZCBIvM10aSuQ445GNYCc/OYHPtLOT/kHh4xgHnMlhiabSKYY5RkwQB1g3EHEDUTcQcwNxN5BwA0k3kHIDaSfAuphZGzNMDqPRxCaY3ARTm2B6HYwxm@AGQyyyCUY3wdgmGN8EN6XF1qUlUgQvOnC5SbquoOM0NpZy0/DTc4pJIuOAhn0dGQNCI28gIXvsTSSUl9qNTKYZp6AyXcNAkUhicw/ax4XN@GyqgjYdQbtk@86JhLGKsidLRGCLug5aqWjh82dB6PzHCD9NQFGgdhEvCxwYA4IJVkqmBPIv@I/tp@z05fHmiQKMIcOu7yE7Pp8R8rDkKGVbfPYkR/Yl29gie7HZjymiNWO2HsdwiLSpPN4ZaW2MsZ24bawfsYLFHH0HImJD4DbYfX7DLbOlz/YWGf16kTsI9xb5higbb3xfLswbH0GecbOS8Z9gy7jl2XaKQFobzADn3HwiA68aFD9umfnCHnt@95s//z/Q737zJ3@FfvsXf/X//af/GYf/I/75P8FmQZE1wB//Cf751/jnX@Cfv8A/f7qVicBHjz2//fO/hNv/6d@h3/7DP7GT/vm/9QRja0SQgqM2Of/sH@Gff4x//i9PML4G/LM/sgFxFk/whdoxrXwA9cf/BSEoDWNZI/vzv0bIEwADw@dI3r3dxx@3Hs6yEazZcE9Cj6/T7V9@pGO2M/6AB/A6d@zmLoAbwL@FXOfwQfCbvgfmjO0UjLU0z/Ej/ACOE6Ua2P7hsQmjGuEhyNtiAEaPs77ghdr/j@gYeQMYBqLJU6YZW4c79Xfq7dmkYtiAhwbq8NmqDioc9q8pgektBfJNZgJLI4ynLWRGytoy4vC3il804Q4gHleyJNPH@imnLDc3THqQc143/G@mulho8TBkP6VJzs2nnGdJ2K0Cd9TNq2aDUl7HwJRx89zWdlYSIUw1aBLItuY3Ziy@IVwIvka3aTmn2xRrpVcdBn/6YGJOtjXSuqAM8ni@AYs57cD7scUV3YW36XUA7pnj6OPOU2D7gD23t7ceaiuOwTKkD3wEw1albJWxTmJ3kyJbSZGtJKDZxkl0TTwSeUUDGTiwXtx94tHOtqWidrNthAv3HLcdMBkwF7TXFYOiPDNGmbeoiUbeVXZvkW@hZB8zTj95UIjOOUMe/5sMgHM3T@Z1W@5HzbyBedtQ@3Nibu/E7LTW@5h28mx1CsI96jWX1i3Hpve13G6BX0HNPga@s6AI83csKPSdBSXi3y7odbPivDvo3@fvt9WOqybWGn6DzO74BzsDFB4a/xxEb6OOMMU6Cfr8MOXJOlOe/kJFvj0Hs0M87Z5Ys3Mau751jg2exFRVU7CXBz5rKkw5VGwFb73NZd@rl5yXpwwVVReM7ac7JftJGcWLny/m1aECo1oQn5wjOa8awBvP9kkSu@PKemRzrNC8/YIYjNpmFLY8n54kRTKfnsD4lEX/hoH4Nszjxxe8FH6zDIS28vvWpm1N86n4BDDT/22cxN61s7UkfuKraU6iFwrJIpjQ8YIMky804vgJfkcSYQmuInnWElukfdPnx0wcqVN1KCgqfrQa536FvrzBjQniNI3QEkRcEPFbFDmTaB8f5PxO1qtfnBVdRXycf50/sotghxlBpL/mMeasvqe4p3eLs7O55TV/Ob3NbXqbX6dXlHTDfE0zicSrPfj6y4qO@jYYAHBDRvTbZASd0xTekLNDyjoav/DAzvDdJA4Eg4fhD1OaBdCsAx4WQT6C6zsD7taEd97j/9cb0M1e/N7mI8Zscwn6ZlrEth@ZohnkLBmFF3wAXvZj3fO2uLVoF76zLGeiQ2Z4QeQhikvBT8FAx9Q0QTHW@70u4m/IPPaIeSP3xE0mYyfuoUmfB9Ek8n4TFZ4GgswthYHPgQxu4XVr3BC4AdFX31dxrOiI0lPtt1z4mCC7Y4qRpxUJ0PE7IsMF537/@2Jlg0hr6SGbcYTC8vv8Iwt3r1UzXgTN2Hsgqg4a9IAcU0IOh9GW2tJ@wlm2X67l6FF7/LFbsoof/P4mQ4AP9quT2OCmWP/X1GfDt67Sd4wIa9jwbpXxQ4wuRvwY4ds2/GUs@nZNySrDOlPGbeUd6@S9Fpe@1uJbUuHKpG2VfJ9IfkvovlvmtkTNRrZRYflfNoS8wZznZJnnfdsY7ZivtpiqvNEJOA63mKq8M6o87VGo65xE05n4BPOMbV/4KQmCZbjO4dqBK0YIc9AnW6DcumG71l3yIilTTtuyWpyYex7boltc9G/vI25BUW4YL@S@rMvk3y2Tf1Mmv1PmugfsFrkFRPE7RTqtgJvna00gC6L5jnbGSXjmDpevqW34KCqn473XL17JeywFkXfuPQaF7BW8x0UfKGXvwHtcIAHDe9wkgYn3@AoCm77l/dl77HYLDKDDLQl8xvGOCsf3vPc47/O/UOSVim65Ye/xuk0B5pN9SzjyYi@v9p1df3W9qioIQduoDCIsMQZcVFyt@8cg@TLwT0Cds78g8WMGRY4IMJ6A7AwaWyOGXQ4MG2HyzjbfvuHj2F2actY3NmsokB7IbC2qYCmZEX3kPfDuKiObMJxKFh/hCgRivXm8nyLEvpmZfYscp3SQUNLIu@UT7oWJPTDwkfR7AN5exJE3@d322kVhN@D30Ykzv0fnG3Lc4ghF2BnAv4cszNSfvF@pFG7rV@dI2a2/3UJv1whwI4ZcELuVCNotnQ42HLZNSWGaqu0KCUnFu33Sdh78cTollt5X2YhWcHrmO8kk2qkZVgzbnd//teps5cOk7aggnHjPPNq9bD0uEF2Mkza6bstStTsfkLClcwbkCAgBi23BCRI4W90EyVjx3jDk5rWLJJprV01C5jB@lm7GmXbpm30Z/ITdL5u@ujnBBAcaMYKtnOtSbP2q/gL7XbXtd9egdpnwqoB9hvX@ofStef3VUfYV5fKm2LcNiBODqODfaxytS9iwHGYHW5b512TtjYmPX2pjG/l2oWvsr6x9l23rOcE3@PZ6bmHjwlaCPt@NnOCF2UnkfUa9tUjkedg1WsK4JAePXfE1pZuqfZ1Wu@L7mhin4DEaLr@4gfXdBt5uPIyPVEB/xXK7l@OXAJJ9inXfxmvqWzsX9q6Dir3E1qeibUWCuif@a2sXLYioPTUKtWqlB4NuMpn0v92KwL0W8m7Gceqr2wTraUskiI/AIa8mxr4TI1U3Pz4onrcuZSQCjAGO7NvY4uf0cb@jy7b0@au@C/ls2C2OOrgmm27A7WglbOpweMiWHL7ahyr7jjgHiWveAr@DZLaGd42wdOANnacnMnw9PWHnnKcnZxTDTbPeRvr9gfNOpcjW@4UPdr2Z3nm3O14AmE3tt9s6C3DOCRK2H8oBfpP0@s3w61wzxZRcZwe8PoS3qNaeEb4o67dfQO3G2O@JBkn1RWJ4ChuJ40eT7VwYGi98EtdKp5yPtqGDj0c1NFVxXiQ9sV82Tg5rNdylV0L2TFlwxA3ELoU8Ub1Fke2Q5e6LkXfDkmOs7Rfxcoq9hOzyJoiEYZjs@ETSMOWYSJp9Qtra9cPwk0yEYOKjBTzuy8IUv58VZHfPavK1BK0yKknDIQgS7ZwUbju4tPArW0OqGMq7J38coA55y65zsqTjE0ZOdXXWgYGdvp2jWwwUSYA1lQ4CZzdfYCx2k0H4eBaGOGkRKPgm4ZK0g6ngVt6PvqV/98q6Hz/G99H3hFvWfjJT0vGp4HNO2eKz88Dm1tK0s2lJ9MDWzqV7ChHlnBqVIfuUYeyjpvk8Bx73bCYctN0mOJl3DzXx4eN0jqkPClE82AMM8bZvDRi4CjbayPaaf@2SqqBfoWiEvOIQyiNWKikWcNg7ezvYIQ2yYmJt7z5HwXh@NfD8Cm8mUh8OsC60ZQ3nd0UZh8kZkxtZRh8ddPaGCu7Kdhdwb@JbN1GYanzYU/BHnycAWAIev2cHE8A7ux8fbM37NisoRf/v6dYg0S2p2Wy2NWX1xnl2mB1lGz24zzGVQHccK9J08UIeZAvl/vJcTbbmYoRp9W5y/WignhxYmnQxzV9oRUqK9aaBu6iVvoit4vloPsszt@J5RYwl87firSFkZSFNz8eTm4HQ0PqsbkhX1etqY0WX2jed4c1YvOt2x0mlSWmNu9zwxhJuUl1l3mmny8aN0MlXzUl1bM7YZS3ZTbQXipHrtHKjy2V5MbHKCbUnxfM3QrIjahcLfhnX@Is2dTdvjRLNi@UkzU4Hy2zeGPSSgQDdy@eGqQt@cCdeNvNXg6Ee78cnzTQXnU8vRW05urpQnivjfHPOB7RxqZyYU0q9PF8Ise6kL18od41Op1/I1RcT1rjTBuNY93pm9lN6IhqdZYXROBYvz0w9Vcllr5JmIVvulOTbjnm37KTqlHlhtpLtSz4tB@Y1k4/OCm3aYDrWpXTVXCQuIi31QrmUy@P65Hx2Xpe12aQQk2qtaUwf3pb6aiRycdOcX/QqlB677PZSjXEkVeAtnr6Kq@o02kpXK/q1Ncs914Runm/mhH6CycVvi@z4urbka/NKo9Gta932NGlcsfJdiRlTtVu@mc1NSpVpim1Vl@XUebk5y@fL1rwfEYdqdjboRq9vE4tKVSh3b@joBTczrwNSvibT48tLY9lpX5Vvq8YddOvrSykmLq1cJ6eLz4W8cd2o0FV9MmrGxspA6ySlvMpf1ssxszzJXiy6d@lybiKI9f5EnbS6cndmSoUxXaKW@clNuy8sStJqwRVjlc4NPS42eDOZHUab9FgU@xO5ZqyG55XVsDnrDwfp2jlTEJ6vBrlOvFHU2OuSEasqS6rXyonSqnEjspN6@qJ81y9mpWslnq8LWv38Ym5FIj1JrC/iK9a6HZdiksXHmEotd3sduLmMNAKVQC5XV6O1IRUplM67w/hVQC0JK7oics/JfECfzWJWYYbfyFtpK7I@jctMqtQKjJKG3k1fXy/6Rvm2ke/y8ip1dz2ZJO4a1O28bKh6JHVZyqbp@oTRz7lxtXyXlJRSbJE7l4vpcnfVTpnFykxOXVSGhcuGXmhN@dt0cdhcLifD1KVQr0yylJAqNBrj/rDTt3pNo75krmP8uB8onherz0Pox51mKXLZziWGs0a0c1VQ5vVWKbBSb7sVLV@dsMV6apZoJaNTam5dprJNU5G0wvl1OnEzkyrFbGHYzrOqINw@81fshGu2lkzKSOo3pdsbzQiYrb4a649y0eXNdY/u3BlG/EKi7qxuopyd6PzVwDIvjWRLiai1G4a9EattOT7vSs@9ujrOTumr9u2K7i9WJatu8mZzosYHyfjk3DKe9dWVfkWlemNOblfzamXMJ6560ipJx1ml1cuL13zvMsJk28OLa6F0MR@u2sI0Mr54nl3wHG/Us73@uZyYW1pAjKbmFapV7d4Ok8/PTF@o9tJSdtJu1MtmpMXRs16zEn@u9AyjxLfLUi4mKbNCrnc@mebvllzLsFazVqIvi8u6HmGKlFXtXXf4sTo0SsYdP17dlu6U61kkcVsbi0lzMGGnElvpiEyyqjUChUBdPu8Pl4nOTJjzYBlqN2WNzWXH4xpVY6fJeW6ZNkzl3Liq9vOXWSmbraQiN1okeTHJn19YA6nT7lQvBpwau@vno4laf8hEBrlqcViPTYfJejUZq@SpVn9502AHhZTEjjg5P75cxrR0JZJL0J1F4@Jm3BopVTmf7VpiLsq31EWyy4lKW1glkvQ1ExiP0pdKlonVE1TbLJjtSmkRDShX5etIfbnkb/vcLMqJzz0jwPdWo1WtI3CqPKo8N9hWZ1bJS@NxJ5HjW0wt12RmK2PBaZU6lS7UFbZQsealxajZZQytcKGl@lZ1kK/Xhb42iGpiv5a1RGbe7d7d3LRryvT2ZnrRSPZrqwE3jndMsZGoWSb1DCZPZ15pl/pWQTTEcWP@rJxbs9sOHWufTyvtwTwwTt/15lHptsZUqrmOyM3KN8Ok2a5a2vWlLMr0NFIb0tSiXV@tTCGrFquL654ldlarrJQznlnriuYq5@XCrRlIF0vZQq3V5HS5VjuvFLLcdHG9qNwmA8KqeT2IS5PnO6quKHJEv2vKyRwTNSLteGGV58fnzOw8N21dttKsxrYvOtfXV@xI5qd8slcrJLrXfDebvbxaXopcp17X6lftFlULKLd3dy261pIrabFSbrTUeHmuX3e7SW6hZm84phyb9hcVK7e4ns260/RloGcKXFRdCQLbWMgVWrgA2UlRwmxez1frxjLyvBo/D@cF9baTzmrniWx@KQ7mwnzFZAvzAG2UrMUgIWmpSKtnnYs9/no4vGrkRlFtrrUS@Th1mRavlU4/P7pOL4Wri0qnNDOF5qAfkwIGo41bN9m20eaX0jmfGM3bRk@Gzidq8VYunzbku0LqSpcCTIrPUXz3mqvTlVH8tno5UBd567qzLMCUI8WKdSauLpXOLDVRLq6M3FX3@SqVGrb7FxMoeDa6G/FSO5Ab9IUbUa5Sd7dXnUmxPuvQ45vb62S9fRFIraL6@TOvjs659LK1qjGMIKaH8/LMimoVPnWeuqrx8qVVbbRFYZhoRm7kc2VFFZTkiMmK7GK@UOjAMp5LFYdirl1V9EKbv0gKap2jaat7Z9a6t6mryDlzwzSnCyZiXC9oRuwp0rJX7fUiAyo3N660bpOdFwMXZrbXHDf4c5mudhvllbqsFCNGO1vNi1ezxVKrLCU9esdXzvNynZdYMEviiWFLb09WuXmf6opWJZ9LJe8iFyBBhiGnF70YJ/CGNrTGdOV6diFb49mkowemFt0I3PWseHrUGRk0X6m0quVFUY@rl8ZYoRIJPnLR1bWk0XieLst5szDqtOVYPt0Z9msXPfq6JV6lb/LNu6QQr9PlZyHdbSYYvhLv8jTbUKdzE0YkfjihKktmoPOyoHPJWe05XpzNAoPlfGYGtLvk@VWqO5zk2TnPBaLZvvrMWZ1LmZGqSWFo1LqL@W2pCxai0pm3Fap019aiV9KF2Lzo1K4nbD3bWJl0Lt3lb2PDns6KijhvRM34ZVkYJnmxULybjAsX5ecy0xOfmQUr6zc30dIFSyXFQM5UBzLdudFulFWEE7K9Wup6MVjlp6OqKFyUIwW910gMmlecXIRhVHquMFqndF65G/TlES2qSq3ZYBjqLhEpdm8bz@x8cFNftVTrQh9eZuty9FYsK2r9tsMWbnS6msyVbvLjxl1@mUrUdbkvtIapljINnEdVnssqlQSVFOZCrtOl24IUZZPWqs9NBJq9604mqQt6lTBWdFYxFuPUcJXun0/Z7l1VPW8tJ/T51Lqr527ZmRBg2TqvUTfmqh4/P@8Grpbn7fJQbpdFnuamy7FxkZsJl4v@TSIbSGlMK1AcdEZWpT7UukU62e@n2GY02o2Zz4P60ripUp1C5SKaLCxNSyxOZlUrdaFlE82l1b6JxSZ3Y6uWaiYacYudq5NiTisN47R6ayQVq3UxLOWEongtGterPj@lEqtZtVxKFQNxgevVe3eMWKSfmwPZHA3F1tVttJmg@fhFrb64uytk6WlSHBfL8jmMiQvu2lo2x71J/6ZmRCVKrfUC5cQqsWre3VQHSr17eT3qL4bJZF2/6IzTs1VPa0iNgLZql/vqeaE@lQurWxC4RCMdH7flYrsr3RYaTI0yE93sAmxwNleRlkO6HGeuRIW5tKbn6dtpNzHpTTr5eaNnTcaJZjKuzoRV0uw@x2dCO9m7nDZpvt9bjAKRc0ptrpa3xZuYXqkutIpZV4UrJhWp3E3a0@KsHZjmr0p9M99ltH6kW1nMAvk4WAWp6046Uu1fjXPlyfmNcXETSVOtkrScpcbnifNAHQaT2diopTpyRJ7TXVruLObCZMpw1QLX0a1@u1QZVAeRFK0FpOTCvEo8X/bqd5ypxRSaMpaJwYILXBTBgihIvXgz0DE1ZgpzEeZ2Hr1ShtGIodw2m7yZV5OTdjQtxEp6R1E7ljruRKSb8@RkwUtXYyonrAYxud3oDqrWajFIT2IDrjlvZ0u3SjeaV7SRZehsIn0V6XDP9akerZlavdLmc8rNlOPERcCSc4VrvTmnBsNqdtAtPc/EeSdWy8ayy9sBE5vdzcessrot9iLjej87EheNbmzVWERzg3NWaUwlbapHaKbVUYqTlNW@EK6oy1VRWI5SN7l6J9a@GqcnUXk4adaZ5aQmifzdnTFjy71h5YYdlOOd3E16ciEaWSHZTouXY9qq9mt3ifxAiDFUYFSe0pF8hY9eFm8D5iUvx5@lFVs1V2lRWVbbUr85nGe1ymDcnlVzF3SOjczPrdo0etGgozMuN00VrvSeLlNCMZ612rXrhDG6y5qdmFqPzFPaXV0a3kYG9RHHT5lECnTw9aB/t2xnG7lFpVe9aBpZZbgSAvriSjkvl0o5hboQu9Vn45lTxVk21q5VejfPN1l92Ir3TaPMWs8CvVwqtcs8zy972bIxqXYum0o5yUwHuevkzWhQUdpqXYpeUXw6OblN0kqTv5wxQqyejZWeO@f8c3meaKgTxeRbxTvWrDZA2ZXj7ZrWW0xX@REjWtFY8daoDQfaHfTW8YqKzC4avUFDHCvWonFpdq6i0yY76SzkSULhtECsmK7VOHYYxZOw@K2qTFX5amjeNqvzK52mR6vETNDOhSuJqkS0YbbcSFxGuPPzXiHdZqfPFSGSuo7NsotIrXEdUOKCVigPpzKTnzTGwo0EU4Zuoj6@ZJpVqT28m@Vv08smter1xbRy2V2oV/nJojCZj1ttKwrTq1anYhjNxq05KM8j/cuk3K@NBq1CKX/D5znOSNaUfLE20Wad/nRxEYtT41L0dnydvJSGiUmyLCx7VzMtXb9clfOji1igp1ymzB5nys81efxc7Ztm/zkpdZo3l3Q3l@QV5nmZNG9HXdqgLlLT4nlMSK7KIzbZVqbz2WxQayhqeVm/uQY2JyPR1nmfzmrdm7rZGVwI/O1FGyz9S1UoN28vteb57cVgNlAoOQrim6f1q/OKUbotTO7YRbmx7EtsYFK7WtTiybiY7gfm8Wl1NCvE493k9LI6LxU0PWFdg9Yf1pf1itCoXlPs9LpXnAQuRZZN6derzjzWyAq3if71QlzE4oWspYxSqTZj3Vye8zepvlZeTNuX7PCGXtylJ8aUa3ONLK@KNSr3rEWXBcssMvHiVeLi9kYYJxaD4ixSzi6a3XLCTFfFbjf2vGgsJkK1xIota76I1Eu1G1OJxa3Ozd3kClohTvFD66aYFK5jwoCRVnd5vaT2lTaXZehLOrJod24C6lB5rgqBST1SimqJImPVOZgZ3@Vml4NEvz2Wu@e5i/SIGsT4YqBlJMp3iefb52tJvx0HklNQOSmxMb@5BpOkb7ZbMetGTPfYVSef6nL90ootXtHZ2MXFLF2ORC4r6UqPMprxKUjL8yJye1mQIzf1Tis2CxSqBWswat61G/nFdequx07r3eb8Ek/GojSzEGvjRntZLVltSUgUJ42imKMC5ZuFUUtrYqPQKep0fSCWYuPJxXnpXJhd8TOrqASYYbm9nD/PpkLq8lrmBF0pNcxRlo/2UpOoxZe17PNVh1pecMVLNp/qpPSJxF@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@jdlPPFbCtxeTWaxK56rJGjc9ejcTNCjSv5yYA2zdRMakolo3iuF6zR3eRmOusvkvOK0VspV9xMGk5ZkdMm3YqSTGRvOs/xGhMtXtPFu5WsRJJxK00NeHFwScuNyW03JRUv6J48ggl0AeR/cns903lRN0bpLtT8eqUk8@3asKNfyKM6UCj3ZxovTtPSZCRE76gG3UyVkl35SuRrvcY02etLt63LaFKcWTB/7RVWV2KBhlZv95qjGXObKILpGos9l7uj6c282jEa8UKnVanHqM5zoyCy5WKl0rkzB2y1xgxLc7OdTF0UWX6am1SLy1w/V16U@Hb3IjAORFoDfl7qZOViZ8AZ1vKOSTN6VhxTiXHiOicWWHMR74h6LH85qkU5uaxatcuUNm3ULyO5y@KNqE50JneTdT@JzjI9leLLoZjNnnfKvfyQyt7kC@NIRzT4hhJYlAlYriRzv//FR4UIuq4QMGquSgNE3j/uHHNx8pWDJ8jJE/jx9p1zJ7Czz/ZBAqLzfDXQAuUEPW38hPCxXQjZ2wzjlxjgrcWT13uLIdY9ToBc8Dke6Ii8uEDc2Qj16DjzmoyPkvI1AsiOJ9lBwftg5PHkXxnH8AUagi5KYBN5os5HeOP/Jm2EI/icD3yaJ/N4srXl6WO3qcEEQpNxigj8DHp@hU9V@AEyki3gYq3k37etz5zs5AfiDE0hJ414QmEPyeqcioEx7aKwWxPHr89moMiBLO7G2ldey8TRbIpJpMn5HkgJmsHpffoxeMRnPEgwJU6ZGjN9MZgM1dFcRDLSxn2LX66eEYrHUBTKivxgH6bJJjI0OSw3Cb8plGac46HssyzJeUX4kCxy2iA@OtOLUGh9xNRH5CeBIP459py8kVJ0NHWl0D7kY3qfeMwoGeZkeq88niiBgN8MZMwAG/DhiB9Y/4k2czwR781H8tQ@fYSu3Ufr8UsLsO@vKqK6qvAj1Wsg8vLf7WdOyGFgbgeactp2f5oLvKnq2zEiliduutMR30bhXWLuVU5JdeHMpSbgrbv1qQQyfm06/vkwS8RO3qbjGn74gI/QOHF8J7Yr8IXSZn1Z4o@pD4SfeAscP05/fOwcCsMjLLcfPpA4yY60aUGS4cPJJ24qr2pLJ7Nkgzy5dTndQnnmw3ur/uD3QLpQfZDJJ/yKKR3AbBCbvTvgCFCTrVG/TRUOVwRlvQ@Kz/Hxn@BTTtBHN8098QfDY7kh5@48mUgip/TA5RQ5oOQMDOR3TpwgsfcSfuiNuBKcee2kD@PZVCP7z2GbXocj@K2YTxon6eucYWOG31LsQyxmhuQSjVsAB17weWxzzhS2m8ZtC@z4Rh6@wvXB@OrkJShAMM/p@hLrRvzwAcY3UEmeD/ZrV33IVG3HSpsMJy@pht9pamAcPsraq3mPEfGDO4EosiV6spU6hlRc13eSp5A85czRO8kjjHtmvJesQzJ@Ges7yRIk289E7k9XId3e6X8HwMReniCuT6b6ZHKS7LMP9MBHgbzYCtuHAgGXsWsRQHbD2O2xmx85R6Ogj3br2MK2I17QP4lY2QBYpH1O58H3G2khqfikb58tF1tl2jxBX9A3C3OcI4HFT6QkULu4fP/RDn60RQD0P1Cl6G26W7jd2uuK7shPGIadIW5tYFYU/fzz1yhzBHFX/thHV/rsFsJ@uFs1tLm1wWO/K3LTrnamlZNpfx7n6Jht7eb6SGzq4XbKyEaF2H1r069FSRlAGYD443Y0dnnyo0@bmHvjER2vtceGj3a3@DYfI2@kB3tEkR4ZRP1NkP9@rnJY7iEnByNyf6Ms8Dlh3Mkbdhpr6NAu9BlAr7n5Ss74HZlxeukvrez31eYA6COdmvDmxFa0PJiGZw6Be8jj7Hbd1gk2skPvsR2P34Ep7SKT3kFmn6f3BAjMU6ABj2yuGnfHREkJ28@kgp5nIrEgcTG3QV42bHKV1ffw6e@hc2HGOUP2DL8WbFcloT2seQO@rjfm19nrLveqeram31@5e/uhZu8nL6YRvZUnInWfYJQ8RgxaH9x0gl6@rYf@dpz5smm@HXvH8L2vK9xGdyXxe0Tw5R1Gf1PIdqsQeUQ7HMckEM3wjSGJHEK4f1DauNY/uTGu26Xdt9@1wDBVJ7vpmGYboZsAhvJ2rqBjc51tVKdz@uKT6Ro3wY0Vht/GaUsFmOwn1LY6x9O5Ehm8t2PXR0cRjmyn4CfZsYWpu5RJomvbghns5gvzT7iZbSZjfkKfHqrqwOcaTI7BQDC4J3QAUNA@zmptVtnm5aZ4KM4xetHQOeXDHXdPIOajE0XGFYjAxqcjm5iIoyHpNie422zZN5JBXhZL0vFoBEW5Tx9gZ0Vb@6Dj1/EYem0CfdibydX4@EwycnKlo@fJSLyjHjx5TsGOobg57Kn1qQfHrxsCw5zBRHtzviVpg5c9qwz2GZ7O6ZZftqcu0okUxjbxutFdL0j/yZqa01MPLmYt8C@/P/hIzwyd7ksKLShzMKr7S@oACYr9jrRjNDPFUAo7Cmcb5x1HmxC/bOKECGICLYVLCyv/f3HX1py2koSfrV8xJpUsSkAGH2fPqfhyLINsqwqDjyTsUInXhUG2VcGIQhBMHfu37/bXM6MLJk629mFfQJpL36Znpmc00x0uyihDljO8iJZMQ/qk40OLdQN@gPnc@Cj8PiSrX3psmcTJI/8uabFQs@aTWcw5ChH7rhNP0VPmT7XGt4jUikGRs8dwsjJl3C@QqUt5VrJalwZSHU6OzRyIL6jJA27pa6mE9gOh6jzplysjscL@4B5EQPee5HKKmos1@dlIdNPD1xpEgcsr9DiSXiYmfHYUKNg6SZb8TuzjvY4HmcJHXKH3ap1i8IFg5IzieAIlx1FQ1N8jAUjBb/hB0/E8S0W2kSfWccpdnmPGFUF2WMeBCNJjvDitDneBslE2wCxgS3z7GXAef1lGQKvEhK6wgDilrOCPUHJQrfPbCzbS8qYsziLh607qLYEsa8qrx4TsKMguq1bOVavqarpwThQbP5VGfzCAI4iz8CEmihvhaERES1lsZOLAIySi8X9I8SdfgPMqJV7mV1/kVwv5lsyXRGWlrMH9NCv0KV@o9ObvrNyzKGXFKi9w7Qti2m2zdykrnubo3n2tbGLRIi3KCh@kTSm1Ms3YK2RUczn/WtP6MmezUCdV8DT/i8xX@r2tWj6lslD2sIgf/4ZqoJB9MKgriytaao2j0Z9y@zHN4RFWwK2SrI72ZrWTnVJtiKjhpErDBCkxd9uD/QzKh7oecbjPlA72DkuW2pL6s7xKhgzJ9qJjrekjOSkxzg8suEeeSQgPZ2/mQDBMKJrQPfdAV16qysscWJTa1GgN7Sm02MGJtdUuvo9j3U/40Z29SJwu92Z95oak/FEyL29aFAXEg@5mab2YiqPJbDoPZaJi6pVZJMO9XIW4fpBox1iBDu4xUqQ4Q3kf5Daej4eb6TiRHyj0SPFC7mmOknRWoK7V90dNiMxn499b742T/gNZhaPwUdiwqfvsEt8oXLaZhcksoT4QEoNTkcwnk1Gk/LqJBV/nkHzWtz/iMkIGMWc0WIaLC6KyfAVP6nIMVbJEB5AXuGeYZSTzO8SKxk4wwh7T0HobEciZZdjjJXsmZjdo2/LKSyjm8OOKAXhEy74cEbLlZO/hnQdYaZahLxZJVm9l/x7PyAQixmP2eQhXq58M4695NPjWOBHbtdrv9dpv9ZzI9FZ1zfptR7g5E0lnbNfqtdrH@o5hNOLJUl5tLA9MwNqpAmBFtDDRX5Buht8RltiwacbgggmZ/kk4/R4OLcPwwiHvAd/MWSJQ5XkSSi/K7OcVKWRbwd89mbsPSUXQsusewwv@MT9L37UDdqxRMXCHaBJOH6KZvGkUf4@GEKC@N3Ubj0bxgjeicWVJygOVHsIZCeW9KYoksV9aRQvbLuwulqSB4ArswO8m/s5@pJUYyE6N4H6fLwAZcKIICHlkMvR6jhLCNxj1oweo0xoC4GUpk4AmgFgbzgfhqzQYTMR/SYNQjA3jwRyeefu6ZbZo9Iu5r1B3D6cRjb6ZgLlVuFqOdmrg4NT1hd85Di5tzxH0fO51Ltym0xRHPRGcOqLROe9xsCpx2mnR6OILu92k1HbguUfdoEMJJdunmiXOMOx2Tzifzz3H90XHE@7ZecslaATes9uB6/gV4bYbrS5N1icVQRBEuxOIlnvmBlQs6FQYq65mZPVE51icOV7jlF7tI7flBj3GeOwGbSA7Jmy2OLe9wG10W7Ynzrveecd3BBgzmq7faNnumdO0CD/hFM6F0w6Ef2q3WiuMdi7bjgfiC1weOUSlfdRyGBPz2XQ9pxGAoeypQcIjAlsV4Z87DRcPzmeH2LG9XkUB9Z2/ulSIMkXTPrNPiDmj/BOpULs0up5zBqJJEn73yA/coBs44qTTabKsfce7cBuOvyuMVsdngXV9pyIQjpNREwySFuXT81HXd1lubjugOaN7HridtkmNfEmCISptqtpkAXfaklsSUsfrASrkwA1QEZenDqV7kClLy4YUfJJaI8gXI4QkxCDPpmg7Jy33xGk3HGR3AObS9R2TGsz1UYBgAu@lTUi7zDXaieiSj6SshtbcCjencI@F3bxwQbkqTRrgu0pbWGyNUyVz6stbxtpPbq9@wHv5lU9thbzuJL7RaTpk8cnoLKUsvUuTzh/Fj3eFPJpo0kx6VV9Bea66HoY387vraHwbY2meVpNfsB@SuwpCFJkIhvrVeCUgs/pQzhXevLm@vrCvaZ3rX1@blV@pWSDjZzWUF9bXSpmKx1HcH/Iyv7C3lBfUwTvl670iHS/n91repZsPptjaGoaqGi4vArDeJlJBCQjYECMj32rsj0UOJX9iLu4VccSM1c0i/XkzTuhn/JS9yLkhl0CDszy3sLWFNSyTgcgnIqWfkHBQEBUZhM8BRLeM0krC8NtduZZHhyW/2qAydR0uO6Nl4F3Z/En1m/BupXp1tT4Ti7umbKxod/DaTTsUM@Y3JTKh2sWaMmdlubXHf6amhhGRUWhKVHyRVZ0@Kb@T1eFfVO4VmrupK3EOB3Jmf3YvsZirbe/srqSfpumyb@HWOWLb0Hz3hetd8d/plSxAHSzC8otEEi3lJ9WtrVwdssrYnkwLw1f9PQotoiHNqZiq70Oe1uEhX7oLztenyXgaPeapp2H4xLPPjrrHxzRygtqdPz7@/s9dQ3ncn84@V@R/D3gQ35GlS1b0IiIzjbNyvaRBds/xi2A5ueg@aD0URGxF3Wic2CeTNvWcKW0EGV9DbgOB3QQRBsYIslFCkIBpSeB@frhpaH1d2zOVApQLrJrg5qH/yBZ@n0wl1oGB9JI5WnKrPeIHsNPur7t4ypBSIKVi4cNktiTNpcUFj3ulY@1wgNc2fK0YRayS1uNJX59BkoLBmMleGHAHn9@UbudakexaNDT6Kzc71yQiNlep0EFaOOQSoTiPE92DZWJEKZ@VvtFjTwUHQhZCPdgzn8R4nNas6uA9cs9ZdQwF@epgn5ro3bsU057ARqqpiJL7/8XQMfnewKTIAw1iBbA@eZTKOc3hTejDf5jib6mp8OoNOLtKY9U7ae46dhSUXe0SXb3rCDJCwsoCynDSIsVh6CI9XSQVZ0FM/5M8GP7/USZr4O/RgpOgZ9LicTgaz8NflCRDlbKi1SsLJVroE2O5Y2qZNPNJvQzMc75h7lPG1DG8R/lhiUSgWmepE3oypFh5jQCg5NjXyPdfOPDlTnzfp5XTIffdDfmlfzoePEzKOiCXnipewL2qsM1V0Ufk8GLKT/g1kUPXQnyVQ/bzyGMGFlw0it0sxdukJGF8qPOYA6a33vOmR9rLWTUhhrru4Zk61VTX0p3/UZ0wymaZoc59JlP0x8G@0s8hiClUGPD1FxA9gPDZpzzDSmyE8wCEruUbnl54l1@oWRwRI2kI5HlZBOyeI@nf8poZU5HypQGnHUAJOG@HKmbTTThbYLoYSejsQySDJspv2Y0JkKi9yNSM0IOvaZHUeZJdpNTzNiX0NaW@O/42RljhUG5x6RJWIQJU3gWrJc76HAxq9Gt8lzLkHyDWgyJ@d8x@VQbyeyW25njlTliw0n@bZBIhi3MB65LmoUxK/cE3JJa0jkaLavRIf4yrqjjXMY1ozcAR69YZ/c8/XBBAV1bOwIrS13G6ifRJTmT7b7X5gifZd9OnHp7UPvM@MUXEUQoOzCozCCTDbsIhzZe9jen7Dw)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- LNUSP (135) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/lnusp)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))

### Explanation

Wierd is a 2D language. Unlike most 2D languages Wierd doesn't care about which particular symbols you use, it just cares whether a symbol is whitespace or not. The commands are decided by the angles in the path of non-whitespace. The IP starts travelling South-East. This answer is in the John Colagioia dialect of Wierd.

I have only tested this on Chris Pressey's javascript interpreter which appears to use UTF-16 or something similar, but I have designed it in a way that it should work on the Unicode unaware(I think) C implementation.

The IP starts travelling South-East from the top-right corner of the polyglot it does this until it is no longer able to travel forward on the Boolfuck line. The IP then turns 45 degrees left to travel East on the Boolfuck line, pushing 1 onto the stack. The IP continues until the end of the line where an x has been added to create a 90 degree turn. 90 degree turns are if statements that reverse the IP if the value popped off the stack is non-zero, or follow the curve if zero; so we reverse.

```
================     x
;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
```

We now travel back along the line until we end up in the first column. The IP normally takes the path that is closest to going straight, but here the two paths are equally close to straight so the IP takes the left one; so we are now headed downward on the first column.

After heading downward in the first column past the emoji and the column numbers for LNUSP we turn 90 degrees left again; so we are headed East along the bottom of the LNUSP.

The section of code that prints 1 is interleaved with the LNUSP.

```
1  1  ! !           x
2   !    !          xx
1      !!           x x
1  x*               x x
53  +               x  xx
1  x*                x   xx
51  +          xxxxxxxx    xx
1  x*          x             x
34  +          x             x
15  +          x         ?   ?@             !
1   *          x        ?@    ?
1   !          x          +   *
1              x        ?  !  ?
1     !        x         ? @ ?
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

left 45, push 1 [1]
left 45, push 1 [1,1]
left 45, push 1 [1,1,1]
right 45, subtract [1,0]
2xleft 45, push 1 [1,0,1,1]
right 45, subtract [1,0,0]
left 45, push 1 [1,0,0,1]
right 45, subtract [1,0,-1]
left 45, push 1 [1,0,-1,1]
right 45, subtract [1,0,-2]

This left 45, right 45 pattern shows the way how 
to increment a negative accumulator.

right 45, subtract [1,2]
left 45, push 1 [1,2,1]

The next operation I use called PutGet pops 3 items 
off the stack. The topmost decides whether it is a 
put or a get: non-zero for get, zero for put. The
second is the (1-indexed) x-coordinate. The third
the y-coordinate. We read The '1' that is the second
character in the first line.

135 left, putget [49]
45 left, push 1 [49,1]
135 right, IO []

The IO command pops a value and takes input if that 
value is zero or outpts the next value otherwise.
Prints '1' in this case.

We then turn left 90 degrees to travel South.
```

I will give a summarised explanation of the rest of the Wierd

```
                         x
                       xxxxx
                      x  x  x
                      x  x  x <- loop pushes bunch of 1
                     x    xx     mainly for direction change
                     x
                    x    Print '6' and exit
                    x   /
                   x   /
                   x  x  xxxxx <-Get from (3,1)
                  x   x x   x
                  x   xx  xx
                 x    x  x
Put 8 on stack-> x       x <-Put 3 on stack
                x       x
                x   x   x
               x   xx  x
               x  x x  x
              x   x  xx
              x    x \
            xx     x  \
           x      x    Junk stack manipulations
          xxxxxxxx     then print '3'
              ^
Get from (8,1)|
```

#### S.I.L.O.S

S.I.L.O.S crashes when there is only one non-whitespace character on a line. So some extra x were added at the front of some of the Wierd lines to avoid crashing.

### Going Forward

Because Wierd doesn't care what character you use it is a good place to detokenize Incident

Answer (score 5):

## 139. [Core SNUSP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SNUSP#Core_SNUSP), <s>6203</s> <s>6136</s> <s>6046</s> 5931 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBk
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOxx4O6O@MoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>+.--._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWW/wwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x


7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002208 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6058 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille,
**139** in Core SNUSP

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3nrZsvayn5cfxoShSokSRNEk99/FFBjNIJ@nGTE86HaST7tx7Mz2YANMfgh4M0I0OMMD01/4V52swmPsP7qwqknrYsvc@SWSLLFatWrVq1apVq6oWSz3OGP7udwf4g2qqvBzIqolMwTBRX5dmgh5EmSX6zElGNBSmKAyV1gfTiaCYxjF1gFiEJIWX@vCMTHUsKNJK0CE@hJCmqwOdmyBzyJlIMHhOEwykTk1taiJV3J8tjFB@oo6kAM45kZQBgJmCrumCSdIjCLUUmZv0@tyLlOiLAjUd0g2UE@QfJz@aiFcnE07pGwAZQyhXzeRL6RcY4giVVd0QMB5eMAwVRyYQWuQF/gVoEkA5XVJL6cr5iySWQedAOqfJwgJxPcPUOd6UVAUnsahRaTVqOzkIS2u62p/yuLrmUIBkzCJRkgWD4qEqZ0izGyaIA@gA6QLXt8AoUdURzoImYxlJiNc01JO5YZBHsgSwBSaBBMxRtIJ0eWighTYBDIY6EbbpMJAiCH1kaAIviRJPSkfCwhQUA4g3gkjix2guyTLqCzJk2JDE@wEZmhpbURYBQaqvUgg@vPaiAuunQwFgFMFhgqABUzETVNwGwBGHF3Od0zQgEpjYAMJNaQKiJJluAwmcIWFhhSyGoPQJ/7S1GKuIU7ZriWYShzigd6oT3Iag47YJErxoKOgCoOTWguSZ65IJLMDsTaOawOmoqQuCd1ekd4qEwlRcgokrEiTNd3rqzlcLbmhGK0eQ00zqQA83ry8pDgVT6PDxBL4pl@uEyldy6MvhPQ5bEgxNrekezotSv0QGfX8vwHfB9uiB/kwBVgq4IiNa1UyaC2hAYMAEAmkOB3EoMAsFNXmrYHT6oi22hMuC6kNroKKC2n5SM36q67iXbpjKjaHSsqoMgJ9QWX2qYH4oKMZAE/AqdDI/EmbANVWx2kidEw43hxI0moGbZKtfWLqGMBS0DciezVGnXEOVpwQOchomFkDgCmTFGIsiaiORk2ScBdIxKotqXTCmsonzTJU@bnnQJUI/iBwyeLWPgSbqDIrjACmJgL402eqBhCgAhoZQSVVx0k//8i/7gwHgSfO8qvdtcW2jvsoTrcgRYkHVICywqsLJhCyA8@PSrexQwIyTpT5n4uKVpV0EIYKUOlench@pUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITcUqR@NOHGlt6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodQJ@z0Eq8QB0QmQlMpqaYQAEtj9wG/b3n07Hn08d7AYjzBr1HhzQ9OAGBCx6RKHhyvyc57fSOojNMzlClPqUtzaGqhFCARy4@pWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q1ifebxnkgpPihKSt/jBhnPQLlu7wmf4u@k44eTF7m3SwQsc4wF91bBw3tdFGgc0idm9ISTlKC2RO2AHdpKU41HzHGcHNyKxnx5GTezIg7IOILFUsXyAWooaMiCoHmYIOvFWgLD7a02TthX0Rc47AofSw8@94Hbt111ggFqulNR3Febkoq1lqwNp6CjgSmKoYH21rHo8hwIj4GVuAmDuR/1iFgTzQ@KhajEueDWBdQDPeqIEemRVo/D@QNYT9oYNj3Igdvt0EJ/qz@DLoAubRqvlLKszqFgQhsevkCDKLhwbgBNBJmtCqWtClklkpjdqo0V0CsYW09AiUBPgr6Aex2odlv0t@oI4OGQBQPYrL6ypYIm3BKw8NaQuOk3SBKhS01AS@hLxAtY9YAOEqxxBRcyJd3QADMGGzRMIBSN7na1Vz3N1Ol04BZ09Yp@t0Phym/3KaxvkCjMkcwpgyk3wJaUAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30ctghkQF7DA0aQ@rw88uyyVhij65bZWBdb7WePSJyWMnYtlRABp2KONsaRH1JB@0kL1@WDgCzF4W7fsAgOwT84HqDBMcQACETFgI/NUG5gSDPhxI/BNnF1CmWerTGopfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aEwMe/ZdiArS6yhMxpsoArhFX@OBMRajOtuJII2/HfE@Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNkhzQZC9r@CcqIq6Bykwco0Wg@ymWO0ABlkDG4MwfjnWF@msawtx3UTQZqA9oOeD/A1NUzOOYbiQzOG0FwRJoZv6smhWFSwstKkvJVO1wj1Z7YF6NqB/0k4JND/tSYsXFSJx6zYcGdQM7DDRQCkYwJ@mIHUet2iA4iTxWQy8leQiCpygsK4uACRAQWCURzSISi6AUmksFd7jCpKuFIRO5/IjF@64Li8EcK41X7LqBGsh1CH2ATb4MjpoLhG0la37iern9o546zGAmHdud3CkSorni/vjx4/uY/cZaPiPHz9B6BSHPuGQD0KfSChAQhguiEMkh5@EcOodyYHjHtzPdw7mhfcBN9sCj04rSfNwd8fH4Qc/d8fa9xC@e0HVgWYD6AC@AR63N5XCQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbqJKtVc/rGWbl6kXPTU0GlZ6tEKjK@PE@jBMJdx7ckPkxInOwTrqmqmSIPheAJdACB7DkeZ6hT6PMw/pIlkFsnsR1awYG8azUnNQrkbBDVJMCl7NNrIOp4IbdoG6kHgi9tzIlFXJ2sNZ1ACP1SR6zDswrb8zjQVD/t2agSnTu1J6lZ8HMdP8AQzyFMDnkcB1XpcR9qACQyIJ51BmMxRA58PQ5JJ6DrShkwSlHgiGtR7TuQXlnnG8etZ6NY4so1xX/rbmdbIWYLcUKaGhitHeLZnOm3DxzBwX@0J8iIWCQiyGDQXqyBWF7EIZd1QoP8WxJ681GK1LwNlQt8PLMQXCZxOWRQ2YQwrwZQFlSSDrD5sNzO17iD3lMvqwOHd0cm1SQltTMn99q9rGwsRZhCQsYrV5Sb0CMZedAcFTN9f5xQlY0guO6CvKHqdQnIbk55ILnsAjm2bCroEnuBjllzi6SE261QVKcKcgJHRgSADVkkKR9fJDY8T@@jZHfF2iOkJ4hSmjHRPUnD4K2CBZIJAir2e9BYo8AWT7tz3gOnT3j62gXANXxlFaIfx5lQ3ZaFv3//b7/ehAV43z5BbwlSHH68Dj8A33FQB8c3WsrPiB3LZ37IEZjSVJY6wgYS@hpLn8HSUk9eB/aixSkaBwJDToXGXTuOCcOILDK/vyJlFuS7I077g3PcXQli8a3pZuRVpQmoEd2xHknH0jewvDEcrP57O67LK9QkWa5lFEjatbbWLsOAGUDl6SyOBhvwGOh37Dm3WVcCQMafWFS@lfK1dJQ1/93PleFfImCjXYwWYhnI96Q0@YjJib0m21WGw6REQZW5sBR9xcH9lrero0mAAJpd9fwsM7GuYAmkcL9BzcntHLJzBAJGBnnsPpy5b17dAnEXhdeAtQKiqTC4/R/iIOPDQQ7Ds4AXNwBabpBeMlbneEptow58vRbhAMsqCkknxPh8TxgPuega8WTrVtLfzYwuB5E8m9@e2VlkJAl4VRUH4Ws@F0UeacHIg1N8KvqmIHZN2E9oDOuJmHBi7MmeAkJg2m4UZNAu5vCe4eEDhsbhsQu@I7YYcZ6HjrbnyJo8m8aosGRppbufhLY34cpaxQYPX0cllkxU/veZvHwx7PFgH1qH9nVrlTTxffUOOvkFJWVNFPBnfEoyg@hbveHWOv2@aCUN1JljX/QPXai9V36CCAjKRDJgsvs7e578mrnjhk1z2c3G8lyqTl/fGH6OyqupDQTFQKMhgM0chq/UwbMuyNXdtFqtvy7QhyaqBGuT6Hi9gQmAY1nW/NG@zTeKUAD@0@tg6vD/bXqLIIIfS5PpG43LyQJVjiQHNweVNCZjqItb09v1bNdxaQ7HsVzXU2uhRFda@v6nax/D/NeEg67A6Xp7YCr5jS@1TZ/a09u0KwrwArznur1yBSZCcQdqaxb3VADo/nHNL5/4PGD3e4q4zemhLYjKDTYczJBMQMHXLjP6HlBZ5v7T@t@moV2jjX6vEVuOOZQE0Nrm@alIUYtifmYNlmG/XWKI8FabCXg1S7Y0EEJv3dMe3E8XY1Ti01z1oYB7eol1DrewJ4TdRjcdz/PSuwuFkCTr5V62ZvapGAztbwxPoGgRqOPA640CZajuNu8W7@lSpv8@5oeb0bLW/QyRO@bkaKfF1m2nHFDcE8n3LbM9PVJj2qhOwIZRvaH8bKVkisq47iEnMBvNIwqtV@rt4j9F6HRPsV7BHoFWlsRHAS17fpnhCb83XCXAyCTMyRTCX@PoWt/cp0p6qyj@ndUCf9iVspoHxiX0VvtZKr2wfe0kbbVYmDLzK0RPfWpOwxhp78gjcwxPlNxu6BlUyyeDwLa38ag3wnVFra0Xwa3NIGLHJwo@h8074LXrruHOzwUQw/i7BzqoY7QTeQ5YMhr/FPtIco5csuOJFWmtZduNscfBC/2hL4JTUDxj8UJgI5PEdi5/rj6aGc3sTaKHi757kIE2WTN/Ip0nQ4RV83VkC3jKJTFURDNrk9IGA5yqywIE1asW@pWSdldi9zC1OuIFQ@KpkbZYd8GYnr0s7wf0LEMfW/gMP2b6iRqxpoKqMhaXh3Pcby0se2nM6eRfbvk7O49XNr/bqIL139fkrNp8yVIfKUBjqpGesn97qGyCRpuWG9V4lgP4hZ4zx7q6tkDSzhAJPaGu2NzS2@SyrsvwtfMaq0VKUqrp/CTaP/av6kPVn4V1yPUiwb19drYMRnLCLDOVv9aKhMIWBylBNVRMC5OktUBmv9VjXvVXqSILe/yYTab1q1JNVDjsOvGO5Aw7n/i3rULyq74Gzt5@Iu9J6R9vw235WECfptleNsXZdOygqvC6Q/W1nvxMd4F336WQqc6aqBxGB83g4n8/rpaxMeM47UADMgSLOQ9ijwPJLMpAsGSaBlUR0d4cOvyyOmWP2GaWQ69iFHh4srGRvO7/QiNdP3cp6d8g9pA7dgYD70H2vHCPGTUAFGaYge0G5HThRIjeLzk3VkcJNiBMDDjs1PbE8JYwhcUYackof2N@CMZSsl6i6td9vOZU08UL5f/2bvu2jBUrTQBPJAJNzoGC/QnUiDNX5J6tcu/S0pnHYxwvjmA/xSjAuPZBNI2MumTBIENcsdY5ahWbC9vSwPR/hoYZV5RYVVqPi4Rv7H5lWo1nU9FXBEki74HUup1K8Kk8nCppLfXNoBGGar/AC8SRZ7/1BCIMppo57ad@Piqgv4CXKPiaMDFGyqo7Jpiam5L/@jeXfAokSFiEcdoon7m1bJSI87BKnEp5Xp0C1g2Ql6KoN4sFMBjU5xdYfdCfBivcifsgRxxuQxIDjdoKLsVxPsukGCuSRG7tn4s3sE0n0HKbr5@075iH1SzShhf/2@7T3i8031y8CcdZw@ZEDcvKM5Wo7mYHkTaobuQ4XLrta2BGQ@L2thcp29vXgMGkux41kQnwIidwJc@JGQnZnFTwKYOc8xYD@AY9egtrqNKlDz9QyNQINE0WxDyuM3hyELK9D4o6FXSJwlsMF@hENsawEeMRGGXiyGCJjL5xJKuNsM4W3dwLpnNCbklXxWSgYCqdIdQ4fU6dnJKQLfRU7xd19f78IMYH7RTz/QBsOc@7vF79gQjfAPRU04OF3NO5A@Uruy2HwjPnxRwPm/i7Xs/vE2hmFXn74pVas5RvNdLPVAG4@W5U9KKj6hNtoCiwLmszx0H1k4m0IbNElwfi69lhrkPUTgHs86JBDp9hN2etdJ6xBbVa7Aq5DK7gGAXNgO/dXsu/Lbwhb6a8BbM0kSsjWoqhGBMmWGbexrUH9jmzhdsHdfQo62@EI3qfeowoJj1woBVwKAJe@kUfodS2tFvxEIqAZv86o93HsQwG82kC8BsBMWpeF62ulW5XbW/nnf4IaazCu/WNrTHC8W2MM8V6NAXCTjeQopIulVj2/mwnEaeNaDoaWjl8YEEnfspxULelSbYdIRzPBwDO0fJw4eaNbDTSTDKknC0TeRDwywISAdEeyOWZg7YKwIguitGyAJu/3QTX1libWbKDSg8QhwvKKCCjIdQDMCq4HWj9yURjWSL12jAPNNYd5M/@DlfmQwBHMBrXHkfdeoH/6l39pOe/emxD@IzssQvhfWOHvacyg1w6IFo1r1mC2tIs1ZBBzCld8wi226oRHLDwiSspUQNIEODgjDMHgFrGb@m7weO7awE9oBGAmVr1Y25LyBP3Bg93HjmkaGxh44hskm@rCAtoBlDXxJnuaYmdqGCDoWDQWYWkgMjBzEAYkC2FAsxB6vccga9RM0lI/9Hh0enqKXAbPyUIqdmIxkj7kvg@7flgTegiwlGWL3CHIA1k2OSDtzM7mOeR8rBdnxV3OzbrRwwmYGVa7wEjlIQEA8eJoxeaHC4ZC1WYVNLoiLEyizpeOjQUGjkK8ggTLpd5BFABEFm7s8/tSdjd7tdiHZUuag9vN4OpgsAYGO3btE52779G9ea882K7fCATm13sESYHwH@/xB19LT/q1J7LnpR8xrg363FBUvH9fAGqRJ0SHwjQb8271FJeNCujF/eJHQAk9AXoWL0gjVTPS2XzxslprvPKkJZDul2Bu5D479d0Hgv67h3XA/ULqHaZmCnSjnCk4rNymarMEhiE262AvydxX2ktK3yi9Y22Svy6bJLwqiGW@FTGZaQYKZKn4NfZNKr0FmLU28V6V6vF@eb57OD27Vw5eFf/jvpcMDoJHWLggdG@QVwzcaI/OKTpb/038YpgRdHzJQq7NKzRrDzrreRP9ti/s@jWzjUOs42SAnWFDZ3RfmNHKVJap4BvuB1D3IG0VRbxBLcIcekHXOKSymNRNgTz1ahlzmxpk1@X1G3G2U@CaSVVrekqc/TkFZia6xFvQBlHQ1iSWeKbDNKZobmY@MJvCS09kgrckkxlQFest0b5EFmA43fFWXKc0hIkUaDr0YMWxcXAFRYYdN4dQN1nqnXCpuwVau9K95/saNDRZMj3Y6XQRxJNEqI3HiyvAnsoC9lk9TT7YDrLI8WP1EVfY2hT4VVM1tJmY5wQnVIe5GcpNATmIgYAupxOAE8mtLuBRQkAVNQCZgY9uh4g7KMVj1yE46Ueh9OBQWPSlAYw0Hq8fVNIvWHbjRMt5fTChdoMetlh1jvd6txnzsxx/tzjG3XFBSekLCw9@yeP4AXMH4t3zzsztdb2SAeJ9bLsi91@6ITvKgjPtXrtx4X2hEJLJtSLY7TvJZHBoUNjVEeYVUGLD1EsQhDHUI044DXmmxI/bQEFEHj33HsVvmLoXBc7weDZHCvL5yIwEbiQhiEhOkYQkGa9WevDbTx46Be2MYw2lj28rSUN3bDD4AGFSiBcd4jWFLJgbeDbupcDghCzHBC0MwPB3jCmaw9wLU2TdD0mxFF4Q0AFqbzLpyIMh6YDAC1JrdPYd2miDTQ@0uJpMHtutsasOkwjE4nSPxgC0e9ScY3ECf21/NeAaVmIAlYWppgQK5fOVoCjQXz0gMxPonYibgpDpXr/zRq5/81YXKeHAIvHCdoADQnff9sq7v8gq2DOH9AmZ1548w7j/wz0e@EV76F/Sv0cH6ZMvnkM5taTBGPOeeQ6HKdYXPvL5DpUjz6GCzZHvvsPT4edDsHYeg66gawFAgUPZewLyDNZR6lA5OeROPYf9VOiI5IBHn8/7BTL80qCDXw65Z/rwO7Am/BCjW73Tc2h4cXdggkH2GejDPeSQ9oPMfPG4kIu8T4uLP5R8PkxD8PARE/BL@r7hI@PKfYMmM@8T28ilBxNHjezaKuuWePV@sMVAO/p4rdGjxJHZ2uN4dIC3X/bak7bPPvrd7w7YGEyiPsXCHvVTKPzx6AAdfHbRRy7d9eU@N3PfcWIo@PRQG9dqN957D0ik@yBbdbERF/oeoSOaOqCPmB/jNP3DDz@A9YnuzoJnwQfvXcD9cOdZnMXjR/5Y4sj/2c1ak2iYkLGs1xMKeWl030D3cY478kVCn5UTSZI0o9@HrzrErx6CJZbCUvIBPh625nZHw@7G9/jVg0@fPsIf@YfP@hFfP5IYO5qAvP589CLP04I6OFt88@cRvtUMCbZplg2BibE6YFn2YEn@HnGYZT/gN8ZjHz9/AD4IPvI5Pv5MJjfIFU@4VJU8oCGAR5F6AMPhQkA9hBYB/KEO@CaH/1Czh//qJv5rj/Ffncd/mTH@ow5@mUr5fu4nGHx0QtTBD6c/pP4RH1IL4CBMRw7Ozh6en32Bu@D3J76TE/zF/9CVneAJ@VghIOLBF/Cd3p2eBs/OFmeBh7M76uALdbB4pg5CLpC7@yPqILU4rRNK73JnNs1P9gy7BOHTwMNdrQRWdNMfOg0chArprD/UaGUOWHiKbh5xYhg/1vPpXLUF0LVSPt3Inxfb@VYN4o2Hx7PPn31B4P3n4NkDULL4he/MlzJNE90@HgXRu5/HPSHrkTrInS1adOAUiC3ZMXVSTOAenu69UNiP1MHdwZ3nU@hTiJGZGcOO2XFZrVr/i0WkGqt@xg/VKiRLC2ak6syQGbJ9kDPECC1mySwXzEStsn0ICvDHTCAoMeKCGTAKo7DsGt37/5OqWq6qgEqFbOaCMTFWRoT7oFotAzIRCh7Bn8QwzALoXDAz@GdkRISe/f6RIdX2Mvf31B1y/SCAKgiy7iDjDsbcbukhGtOevjyHYk93xFCIJh/uhIVkPriQ3/14f5dMJt0PJwe0cX9PW9rRFYq4TjDI8/PjYy7dTD8@0njdZHF66PvsC3yGT@rMd2rfPh30z04@3R8HsIBbQh58PKBPP92fYZ5D@JT@2Z1ljQruH@8pt2fe6XTwtzOfza0QCVhx9511Kr50aIiyQvhhDp/ZG/l3A4vXUubx3EUfvjx7vd4P9@4Tt8UgjwcJYFV7XOz9IiSikMtLzO0kjFVsGFtEsaj37CwWhedYwhvwMCTZynLv0jTt3hUk0/cgcatJpdK6zi0JUASGy3sXpz/eu@5CD6lUMkqio4FkDKl6IBn2urze79nTU7uMkBeiXe6FS9Xd6Mvz9p/ny/Oph3y8@M/rxZH29czrgWRvFJ4WXzyLU8@pB8dBFM715fkMBwncFwjdebwP3udnKw6uHu@phfPMC3zDaxT/hP@qgQwNuQ@eD7CZo6BI1OvpLQVvJOZJ@JL2X@ojVMDjCrvDUC@Xm3Pf3X0@Ch/FI3efHo4ejjynR8Gj@7OHnUHE6z5A0EUckU6xB5hv1EHwpO5iQy43FvETvNmgykJQVgconDzZFQb3o@fo5SfBJn1Hvs93R8mkVfbR0Y8foTcCOijMBZ8DkF/kQadnp2uhWmNceM8A9guymQzh5y8gZ1YiWE0eezvh/n7BkG7uRSe91OGXA@75hOBHzy73yY68Evwe9wnZb3J9cR1y@h374Hp2HX7pPWPz8oj1EismGjk5OYpY4XgCwuyR11pCjTLw5IQhRTA4niiEkwMsTm7guRdqleoJA0kBk3KHSb5oNEqH4Lr4RSwfWlAneF/G2gRyBVxWB0KJJMF3gAwjScEMpgctP0dxBoZkGb8yoIriRysepmKoJwhgDQuyjBcU8UwFDHa5P4fZ8UfqAPQXWEWGAJ9JjROmgjCfTufC@pOVjGNuhDwjmGnjz0@//oOffv0//vSbP/npN3/w02/@/Le/@vM/gO/fwPdPrPuf/IdkFF9/@6v/5X/76a9@A5H/Bb7/Gb7/6be/@je/b33J89/B9//eivs7@7sFZ30pwPXPf/urP/3r3/7qX/wFfP@d/f2Ll9@f/uw/Wv//j/2Hg7/56c/@Dl/shz/4E@rv//bX@P9P//bv//Ov8f///r/@/d/@67//5/@eBP7SCvy//@4/WFco/M//@Kd/84dQpz/D4X8GYfhHvoD18dkAf4QjfzxkwEBE9z9uQ/5IszD2IHor8o/Qj/fYaZHdQAL@f/sjzcDwyFiQa5zbkH/821/9q7@G2B8/I4izIf/QyW7L0A7kDp1Q0B8B5F9tAfzRT7/@/Z/@@n/46dd/@dOv/zkFdi78f0QfqRDCd3yhWAvtRxJaHFHRMMipE2Y34XCEhKNw3Wdy4N2XT593oizcR/uACeAnkv5xrwWDyzhyaNtX2Ecn/14Mn9BnSIYxiwxbC3zFDxCDw0TlkZsTtbABybMFYz9v5bRirGe0lX03HkduZXRu@6KtBFKkA4RsZAu7ULRBb1eDciizgBevIihkV4@iqDhq1eBSL55fNLfuzXw6e0HFUKZayb24RW2gKCrlC831Y9xKdbJG1yi6@VLp5aN966pTxHNYO5EzCRbk1KDg6SnLUmeNfBMimlXEhpggdXaDFkFUq10bLpdKYaX4EUXjfn8wGIQLvvvJh9yDh987IOzbdvABVcZ7A0nWctWQcA4I6UISb06DLp0rxDegh4@mmGpvR8INR@GgLg2GJjLn6hrAMAywoNbGlWNYrQ2sDnUBunuCX8bGB4GYeFIqiYihgljTh0LJRDSRDIcS/kQyEYmysWjUz4b8bDwRTzJ@mI4m2FgimmT9iUgyHIlEkn7gVzQZpw4EpS@JNA0zEtblQiQgKTx@y/AUv66pBodn1EFfECVF@IAWnr73w0HfiUDTBHKFE/cMctG0i41RePPuaJFyhcKAHoUZ0BIuyrVCPDpgsokwA7OfHn7IJOLpWNjleiQp8MkyLlcfP8SZRCETd7kE/BBNMEw843KJ@KFQyDKFgstVtR7wx@VaOg8MAwUN8VM@xmA/b5eEH7JpC26EH0IJXJTLNbZSrIeJ8xAHMAU/hMMYAXK5ntboMHLdKipBcpnWA8Nksi7X1KpFAv5cribBF4a/BGRKW0kRUsEMSWLwo8uVtR4iBN25gwE/5PFDwn4oWCkYENDJ8NSTOX7scg0gONBhzHa5FiR2KoDIQwj7PCom53Lx8MAvOQXyiUNTWKWX6UEGPtnM42AxGCzOeZwiNaeDnU@@YKeMXqbgD0kZN6eL/SmT5XTgJC2q9kfHKUpv@fqzwilPb6bIWynVZbVfbeIPSRkMnIRBdf0hKXs/OEVUbTBrtQPPQB9FsE1dGwQkhdzlxcJ1AkJN4e6Flh7vFzKv8yBDWgnQ/T2MfwqzjuinacIVi7uOj@Du@uQKQ3DhQYwb7EiX@97l8t4lHz654lHXsfvTp4D7O/YTcsWTrmNXPO5C3hNXCPpm1OWKoRAI/S2YXsIg4EafXCe6YE51BYVOnjEFqxRzQihBTx585/z42vN@scF6J8941RjIfPKsfCnWj1beT5himD7BRNN7vASD1XvyTNOnWHOweBWCps5wnpS1zgxwILBOiqVb1soBwRQzGETwDQQonK6lLD54XEkPAttQlOB67yKms7X453G74yG32@s@ASQfkWtLo3pPCK3I4qnHYYwLWAGMScJMz669JxmAeQgKJIHyVyTp42PD5HS8GkxKPEauWNKFo/GZdEmnsM/@AOs/PupFT8/@O8qyi2MsdfBM9fGLiZEkOkme4NUZmLCdntl5rtAyPvBdbJF8Qh26MdHu8M709YBcD7EtdRAIqxH14PDwkDo4bZ65wq5q8HE9KT@jyZrO/dlJJJXF820wtYL3j6cff/4SF84cPPvsLEyd4YW3V59IhNIF7LfUx8faWfPpRBTzdYCMA0Bz4vuHfKBkKgVIqRM85XIdaLi/8PISL/yhe6uip788IBNuVPvi@JFMFbLVdVzGGxse7rhBXiG/e0DeX1Yk@UsiHDgjK8NYQhG09HMj@X38@8T35Va1VS18Zo4Tx4n7e7s5/aybdZOmspekPsNIJtXz1IHxo1eNsr9ULk8OjjV3OOIGA/Q@dWDVno17D85C8aDBLQ8ebC9MTySOJRaeySwsxKIDsbP7me88zCZkrQ6KSvxefzCQQr9X/uHHQ5p2u8EgPjy78/2D1mCCjwcPsV8GTq3/U7igbNUi0BWLurzYt9X4/vH7xwMEMzHkCkVxb/LRyJprbc8MPYsj5fsjBf6EI4P8CQJ5VI5OzyDKgAj7WcAQgveIpunrEBgQyWQsETugfkfT7@0LQ@p6o0QUBN2YTvbtlKR1qczhXSRlvVsCgfJ0Jehwd86qcywNhE0NvBWIbY3tONv82IoiRzzuxi0NGnuj4ViKwiGJHB2KRKyiPHitwSReRegIH7CJnW691BfqA@Ca8iZxZIPLCUV9wB5V@NHjwPnRd4bpxd4mjJf68MHWtYYZNMxHjBxnsiMD7An1TGH2cP2@gfAmFnEesTx1OeyfpGrWOzjyElmZDDKYWEYTcbLF5W4RfIREiwqozREiJRLKceWs4j9YYL2piEkpFEt5yINSSCSboXZul97DRymR6n0UvXbhiIEojAWDE04RcAwI6CDSQ3B7J9gdmPcQSB9icbpINlUBCoxIP6HEj0Q74x1@fIDsGL3Iy6oBiK3SPVYN0NGjXaxdB2cIw5UAFuLakfGBjHP6gPfbrYfPprh78KIvjtOhB6eiUxTaeEXauKAxrFNQSUZ@0rcEh5xRZbOZYGMf/NC0J5bzmmcNZ8dsGPVMHZn@yYnVVNoJdeXhvV/wptvJLyfffcd/r91NHk68k5SJ7z7fBIarsUeyQI7M1CQF4qHdSQ8nJqgI6SE18V558DOMhDCwP1OixWzDa9cNaq6kgBa8MW94/as7JfBL5cFfuFN8QPLUf3SbWvm5FONfwFeC4V72P6VYux5Qppla@ZQT7hS@eP9vxzEQhm4fd7IThbOMPXJqdcc9pIAfMmT0@QpQGaDTuJN9vgcvFC5D4uuMJ/J333E@@WxxIgcCXgz1ffhT4c6EwIMvhZ@PPdzp4tPqbgr5jz1wT0ExsheIh3w2r5/XtAN9J8Bjq003pFs0LjB5CyBvkkod3X46uj1Kffy4ulsEJg9@i/3HzEYaMPELTPzJluOl5@jWi16whKz/eVy/kI5/ETwykMsv@XzAZL@2ldOi8OgWUjQYP22qn7G@JIczOnvLWMJsZ0HrLCty6g1ZYCZnSBrk3Fyzj92mIW/a4CXJBrf83TUJZogcPu3RjxRVCXAEAqfZh8XixPvFp0@UU7TtyQYlY@XSg0kynmmSswJ1vBhJDh623mb6mn7dp4Ydnbue9jWKt3kEU8xwbKu7EtVEOpyh83cYBKuBL8zziaWxLP9FUDZEewAM0R4YLoC1CGaSrSdsyJSdCK3lNBDkwnpCtF7ZwYcmGVg/gXrb9HxQIRYZ0Jn3kCH5Rymim0CeJAgh6ZSUBwHoKtQHqASmAddBekBnoMjQd98h@/E0BfPaOB4LMBiGG/lYDPSKUij8GygFHJjKEcgo1oekEKDtA07BXrc7BUX@cQXZTvMeyOAb@S3f@SDxnfdMFcN6ZQTzzWuRgdviw4eRLxWxCYJ/Yq5Dfkh7/t2BPdwfg7FSrrWa@Xo53YArzDcSm/Noj9cnl746r1DD5xD2JIX4mPJcnRW6lzyYMGA8mvhYG3wucR9dtkooFKrk/PgldGD9gbUKBAPq8RqTYJADvoygqg/ouTSW6N0DzfEZssSdlRyfHnAOlMXkkMFZ3rzIsnmPxcCrPDCY22/O7hxpPREMwz6GMeCcbE1O7yav9EzwmynQC@1jG4mnkOPsQFxr8Dq8nzhs6dJAIscVDy0EO/nJCXumlZ30Dwoft9jnTA5LNJVMMMwxYvw4wDqBkBMIO4GIE4g6gZgTiDuBhBNI2gHWwcxamGFyGA7HNsH4JpjYBJPrYITZBDcYIqFNMLwJRjbB6Ca4KS2yLi2WIHjRgcNN0nUFHaexkYSThl@BU0wSGQU07MvICBAaegUJ2SOvIqG8xG5kPMnYBRXpKgYKhWKbZ9A@DmzKY1Hlt@jwWyVbT3YkjFWUNVkiApvXddBK@QU@XxaEznuMsGM@RYHaRbwscGAMCCZYKakCyL/gPbZeWNOXxxvnfIwhxa6fITs@fxHysOSoZEt89iSH9iVb2EJ7sVnvGqI1Y7bebLCJtKg83hlpLYyRnbhtrB@xgsUcfQMiZEHgNth9FcIps6lP9xYZfr/IHYR7i3xFlIU3ui8X5o2HIE85Wcn4T7ClnPIsO0UgrQ1mgH0uPpGBFw2K31xMfWGPXb/91V/8H@i3v/rT36Cf/uo3/99/@p9x@D/iy/8JNgsKrQH@5E/x5d/iy7/Gl7/Clz/bykTgw8eun/7i1/D4P/179NMf/KmV9K/@2uWPrBFBCo7a5Pzzf4Yvf4gv/5fLH10D/vkfW4A4i8v/TO2YVh6A@pP/ghCUhrGskf3F3yDk8oGB4bEl787q4w9b7zlZCNZsuCOhh5fp1pUf6pjtjNfnArz2E7t58uEG8G4h1zl80Pum74E5Y/nXYi3Nc/wQv8tiR6kGtn94bMKoRnAA8jbvg9FjLy@4ofb/PTpGbh@GgWjywmbK0uF2/e16uzapGNbnooE6fHaqjQqHvWtKYHpLgXyTmcDSCOJpC5mRspaM2Pyt4B@ScAYQlyNZkulhvZRdlpMbJj3IPo8b/jdTXSy0eBiyXngk5@JT9msZ7FaBO@rmRbNBKS9jYMq4eQVqOyuJECYaNAlkW/MbMxY/EC74X6LbtJzdbfLVwosOgz89MDHH2xppXVAKuVxfgcWctuG92OIK78Jb9NoAd8xx@GHnhap9wK6bmxsXtRXHYBnS@x6CYatSlspYJ7G7SaGtpNBWEtBs4SS6JhoKvaCBDBxYL@6@PGhl21JRu9k2woV7jtMOmAyYC1rrin5RnhrD1GvURCPvKrvXyLdQsg8pu5/cK0TnnCGX91UGwLmbJ/WyLfejZl7BvG6o/Tkxt3didlrrbUw7ebY6BeEe9ZJL65Zjk/tabrfAd1CzD75vLCjE/CMLCnxjQbHo1wt62aw47w76t/n7dbXjqIm1ht8gszr@wc4AhYfGvwDR26gjTLFOgh4vTHnS9pSnN1eRZ8/B6xBPO6fO7Jy2rm@dRYMnMRXVFKzlgc@aClMOFVvBW7/Wsu8Xl@wfRxkoqi4Y2y9KStZLJ4obv6rLqwMFRjU/Pv1Gsn9KAO87W8dB7I4r65HNtkKz1g/AYNQWo7Dl@fgoKZL5@AjGpyx6NwzEj0EevwngpvAvx0BoK79nbdpWNY@KT/EyvV/HSexdK1tT4seeqmYnuqGQNIIJHS/IMPlCQ44f499AIizBVSSvLWKLtGd6vJiJQ3WiDgRFxW8p49wv0Bc3uDFBnKYRWvyI8yN@iyJ7Eu3h/ZzXznr1s7Oiq5CH867zh3YR7DDDj/SXPMac1fcU9/hmcVY2p7zGz6e3sU1v4316RUk3zJc0k0i82oPvP6/osGeDAQA3ZIS/TobfPpjgFTk7pKyj8Q8aWBm@mcS@YPAw/GFK0wCatsGDIsiHf/1kwNOa8PZb/H@/AZ3s@W9tPmLMNpagbyZ5bPuRKZpBDoRReMED4EUv1j2vi1uLdu4by7InOmSG50cuorgU/EIJdExNExRjvd/rIP6KzGOHmFdyT7xkUlbiHpr0mR@NQ283Ue6xL8jcUuh7bEj/Fl6nxnWB6xN99W0Vx4qOKD3V@hULD@Nnd0wx8uIfATp@Q2Q4/8zrfVusLBBpLT1kM45QWHybf2Th7qVqxougKWsPRNVBgx6QEz/IOSvaUltaLwvL1o9n2XrUGn@slqzgd6i/yhDgg/XTSKx/U6z3PfVZ96yr9A0jwho2uFtl/D6ggxG/kfe6DX8ei75eU7LKsM6Uclp5xzp5q8Wl91p8SyocmbSskm8Tya8J3TfL3JaoWcg2Kiz784aQV5iznCzzvGcboxXzboupyiudgONwi6nKG6PK4x6Fus5JNJ2JTyFPWfaFl5IgWIT7DO5tuGOEMAd9tATKqRu2a50lL5Iy4bQtq8WOueOxLbrFRe/2PuIWFOWE8ULu87pM/s0y@Vdl8jtlrnvAbpFbQBS/U6TdCrh53msCWRDNN7QzTsIzd7i9p7bho6icjvdev7gl97HkR@6Z@xgUsltwH@c9oJTdffdxjgQM93GDBMbu4ysIbPqW@0f3sdMtMIAOjyTwGcfbKhw/8@7jrMf7TJGfTHTKDbqP120KMJ@sR8KRZ2t5tWfv@qvrVVVB8FtGpR9hiTHgpuJq3T34yZeBfwJqH6MFiR9TKHREgPEEZGfQ2BoxrHJg2AiS32Tz7Bs@jp2lKXt9Y7OGAum@1NaiCpaSKdFH7gP3rjKyCMOpZPER7kAg1pvH@ylC7KuZ2dfIsUsHCSWNvFs@4V6Q2AN9D0m/A@DtRRx5k99pr10UVgN@G50481t0viLHKY5QhJ0BvHvIwkz9wf1OpXBbvziSyWr97RZ6vUaAGzHggFitRNBu6XSw4bBtSgrTVG1XSEgq3u2TtvPgj90psfS@yEa0gt0z30gm0XbNsGLY7vze96qzlQ@TtqOCcOId82D1svW4QHQxTtroui1L1ep8QMKWzumT0xQELLY5O0jgLHXjJ2PFW8OQk9cqkmiuXTUJmYP4zbEpZ1qlb/Zl8PtkP2/66uQEExxoxAi2cq5LsfSr@jPsd9Wy3x2D2mHCiwL2Gdb7h9LX5vW7o@wLyuVNsa8bECf6Uc671zhal7BhOcwOtizz92TtlYmPf5zGMvKtQtfYX1j7DtvWc4Kv8O3l3MLCha0EfbYbOcYLs@PQ24x6bZHIs6BjtARxSTYeq@JrSjdVe59Wq@L7mhin4DEabj@7gfXdBt5uPIyPVEB/wXKrl@Mf@SP7FOu@jdfUt3YurF0HFXuJrQ8Y24oEdU/819YuWhBRfaznqpVSFwbdeDzufb0VgXst5N2M49S72wTraUvIj0@TIT89jH0nhqpufrxXXK9dykgEGAMc2bexxM/u415bl23p8xd9F/JZsFsctXGNN92A29FK2NTh8JAt2Xy1Dkb2HHE2Ese8BX77yWwN7xph6cAbOo@PZPh6fMTOOY@P9iiGm2a9jfS7A/u3kUJbvx98sOvN9MZPuuMFgOnE@vVaewHOPozB8kM5wL8Uvf5B@HWuqWJKjrMDXh/CW1RrzwhPmPVaPzDtxFi/Aw2S6glF8BQ2FMUv4lq5MDRe@CSulXY5Hy1DB580amiqYv9Q9Nj6MXFy7qnhLL0SsqfKnCNuIFYp5P3hLYoshyxnX4z89is5itr6oV1OsZaQHd74kTAIkh2fUBKmHGNJsw4bW7t@GF6SiRBMfLSAxz1ZmODfXwXZ3bOaXJagVYYFaTAAQaLt074tB5cm/knWgCoGss4hGgeoTX5F1z6k0fYJIwek2uvAwE7PzikoBgrFwJpK@oGzmy8wFrvJIHzSCUOctAgUfONwi1vBhH8r70fP0rt7Z52PF@P76HnELWu9eCjp@GTvGads8dl@H3FradretCR6YGvn0jnQh7IPYEqRfcog9lHTPK4Dl3PMEQ5abhOczDvng3jwyTTH1AeFKB7sAYZ4y7cGDFwFG21ke827dklV0C9QOER@qhDKI1YqKRZwWDt7O9ghDbJiYi3vPlvBuH7Rd/0CbyZSHw6wLrRkDed3RBmHyXGNG1lGH2101oYK7spWF3AeolsPYZhqfNhT8EePywdYfC6vawcTwNu7Hx8szfs6KyhF7@/oZj/WKajpdLo5YfX6eXqQHqbrXXjOMCVfZxTJ03T@Qu6nc8Xe8lyNN2diiGl2rzO9sK8W7y806WKSvdDylBTpTny34UXyIrKKZsPZNM/ciOclMRLP3og3hpCWhSQ9G42v@0Jd67G6IV1VypX6ii60rtuD65F42@mM4kqD0uq3mcH1QrhOdJRZu5UsGtdCO1sxx5WROWWX1Xgn1porRqbdzAwvl8X5eFGMqV0pmr0W4m1Ru5jzy6jGX7So21lzGGtcLMdJdtJfprNGvxv3@ehuNjNIXPD9W/Gykb3qD/RoLzpuJLnwbHIpasvh1YXyVBplGzPep40KxdiMUmrF2VyIdMY9@UK5rbfbvVymNh@zxq3WH0U65anZS@ixcHiaFoajSLQ4NfVEKZO@ipu5dLFdkG/a5u2ynahR5oXZjLcu@aTsm1VNPjzNtWiDaS8upavGPHYRaqoXyqVcHNXG59PzmqxNx7mIVG1OIvrgptBTQ6GL68bsolui9Mhlp5uoj0KJHL/g6auoqk7CzWSlpJcX08xTVehk@UZG6MWYTPQmz47K1SVfnZXq9U5N67QmceOKlW8LzIiq3vCNdGZcKE0SbLOyLCbOi41pNltczHohcaCmp/1OuHwTm5cqQrFzTYcvuKlZ9knZqkyPLi@NZbt1VbypGLfQrcuXUkRcLjLtjC4@5bJGuV6iK/p42IiMlL7WjktZlb@sFSNmcZy@mHduk8XMWBBrvbE6bnbkztSUciO6QC2z4@tWT5gXpNWcy0dK7Wt6lK/zZjw9CDfokSj2xnLVWA3OS6tBY9ob9JPVcyYnPF31M@1oPa@x5YIRqShLqtvMiNKqfi2y41ryonjby6elshLN1gStdn4xW4RCXUmszaMrdnEzKkSkBR9hStXMTdl3fRmq@0q@TKamhqsDKpQrnHcG0SufWhBWdEnknuJZnz6dRha5Kf7F3VJLkfVJVGYShaZvGDf0TrJcnveM4k092@HlVeK2PB7HbuvUzaxoqHoocVlIJ@namNHPuVGleBuXlEJknjmX88liZ9VKmPnSVE5clAa5y7qea074m2R@0Fgux4PEpVArjdOUkMjV66PeoN1bdBtGbcmUI/yo58uf5ytPA@jH7UYhdNnKxAbTerh9lVNmtWbBt1JvOiUtWxmz@VpiGmvGwxNqtrhMpBumImm583Iydj2VSvl0btDKsqog3DzxV@yYazSXTMKI69eFm2vN8JnNnhrpDTPh5XW5S7dvDSN6IVG3i06smB7r/FV/YV4a8aYSUqvXDHstVlpydNaRnro1dZSe0FetmxXdm68Ki5rJm42xGu3Ho@PzhfGkr670KyrRHXFyq5JVSyM@dtWVVnE6yirNblYs893LEJNuDS7KQuFiNli1hElodPE0veA53qilu71zOTZbaD4xnJiVqGalczOIPz0xPaHSTUrpcateK5qhJkdPu41S9KnUNYwC3ypKmYikTHOZ7vl4kr1dck1jsZo2Yz1ZXNb0EJOnFpVuuc2P1IFRMG750eqmcKuUp6HYTXUkxs3@mJ1IbKktMvGKVvflfDX5vDdYxtpTYcaDZahdFzU2kx6NqlSVncRnmWXSMJVz46rSy16mpXS6lAhda6H4xTh7frHoS@1Wu3LR59TIbS8bjlV7AybUz1Tyg1pkMojXKvFIKUs1e8vrOtvPJSR2yMnZ0eUyoiVLoUyMbs/rF9ej5lCpyNl0ZyFmwnxTncc7nKi0hFUsTpcZ32iYvFTSTKQWo1pmzmyVCvOwT7kqlkO15ZK/6XHTMCc@dQ0f310NV9W2wKnysPRUZ5vtaSkrjUbtWIZvMtVMg5mujDmnlWpUMldT2FxpMSvMh40OY2i5Cy3RW1T62VpN6Gn9sCb2qumFyMw6ndvr61ZVmdxcTy7q8V511edG0bYp1mPVhUk9gcnTnpVahd4iJxriqD57Us4X05s2HWmdT0qt/sw3St52Z2HppsqUKpm2yE2L14O42aostPKlLMr0JFQd0NS8VVutTCGt5ivzcnchtlertJQxntjFFc2Vzou5G9OXzBfSuWqzwelytXpeyqW5ybw8L93EfcKqUe5HpfHTLVVTFDmk3zbkeIYJG6FWNLfK8qNzZnqemTQvm0lWY1sX7XL5ih3K/ISPd6u5WKfMd9Lpy6vlpci1azWtdtVqUlWfcnN726SrTbmUFEvFelONFmd6udOJc3M1fc0xxcikNy8tMvPydNqZJC99XVPgwupKENj6XC7RwgXIToISprNatlIzlqGn1ehpMMupN@1kWjuPpbNLsT8TZismnZv5aKOwmPdjkpYINbuLc7HLlweDq3pmGNZmWjOWjVKXSbGstHvZYTm5FK4uSu3C1BQa/V5E8hmMNmpep1tGi19K53xsOGsZXRk6n6hFm5ls0pBvc4krXfIxCT5D8Z0yV6NLw@hN5bKvzrOLcnuZgylHghVrTFRdKu1pYqxcXBmZq87TVSIxaPUuxlDwdHg75KWWL9PvCdeiXKFub67a43xt2qZH1zfleK114Uuswvr5E68Oz7nksrmqMowgJgez4nQR1kp84jxxVeXly0Wl3hKFQawRupbPlRWVU@JDJi2y89lcoX3LaCaRH4iZVkXRcy3@Ii6oNY6mF51bs9q5SVyFzplrpjGZMyGjPKcZsatIy26l2w31qczMuNI6DXaW912Y6W5jVOfPZbrSqRdX6rKUDxmtdCUrXk3nS620lPTwLV86z8o1XmLBLInGBk29NV5lZj2qIy5K2Uwifhu6AAkyDDk570Y4gTe0wWJEl8rTC3kxmo7bum@yoOu@2@4imhy2hwbNl0rNSnGe16PqpTFSqFiMD110dC1u1J8my2LWzA3bLTmSTbYHvepFly43xavkdbZxGxeiNbr4JCQ7jRjDl6Idnmbr6mRmwojED8ZUacn0dV4WdC4@rT5F89Opr7@cTU2fdhs/v0p0BuMsO@M5XzjdU5@4RftSZqRKXBgY1c58dlPogIWotGcthSrctrTwlXQhNi7a1fKYraXrK5POJDv8TWTQ1VlREWf1sBm9LAqDOC/m8rfjUe6i@FRkuuITM2dl/fo6XLhgqbjoy5hqX6bb19q1sgpxQrpbTZTn/VV2MqyIwkUxlNO79Vi/ccXJeRhGpacSo7UL56Xbfk8e0qKqVBt1hqFuY6F856b@xM7617VVU11c6IPLdE0O34hFRa3dtNnctU5X4pnCdXZUv80uE7GaLveE5iDRVCa@87DKc2mlFKPiwkzItDt0S5DCbHyx6nFjgWZvO@Nx4oJexYwVnVaM@SgxWCV75xO2c1tRz5vLMX0@WdzWMjfsVPCxbI3XqGtzVYuen3d8V8vzVnEgt4oiT3OT5ci4yEyFy3nvOpb2JTSm6cv328NFqTbQOnk63usl2EY43ImYT/3a0riuUO1c6SIczy3NhZgfTyuLxIWWjjWWi9Z1JDK@HS2qiUasHl2wM3Wcz2iFQZRWb4y4smheDAoZIS@WRaO86vETKraaVoqFRN4XFbhurXvLiHn6qdGXzeFAbF7dhBsxmo9eVGvz29tcmp7ExVG@KJ/DmDjnyotlY9Qd966rRlii1GrXV4ytYqvG7XWlr9Q6l@Vhbz6Ix2v6RXuUnK66Wl2q@7RVq9hTz3O1iZxb3YDAxerJ6Kgl51sd6SZXZ6qUGeuk52CDs5mStBzQxShzJSrM5WJynryZdGLj7ridndW7i/Eo1ohH1amwipudp@hUaMW7l5MGzfe686EvdE6pjdXyJn8d0UuVuVYya6pwxSRCpdtxa5KftnyT7FWhZ2Y7jNYLdUrzqS8bBasgUW4nQ5Xe1ShTHJ9fGxfXoSTVLEjLaWJ0Hjv31WAwmY6MaqIth@QZ3aHl9nwmjCcMV8lxbX3RaxVK/Uo/lKA1nxSfm1exp8tu7ZYztYhCU8Yy1p9zvos8WBA5qRtt@NqmxkxgLsLczMJXyiAcMpSbRoM3s2p83AonhUhBbytqe6GO2iHp@jw@nvPS1YjKCKt@RG7VO/3KYjXvJ8eRPteYtdKFG6UTziracGHobCx5FWpzT7WJHq6aWq3U4jPK9YTjxLlvIWdyZb0xo/qDSrrfKTxNxVk7Uk1H0subPhOZ3s5GrLK6yXdDo1ovPRTn9U5kVZ@HM/1zVqlPJG2ih2im2Vby48SidSFcUZervLAcJq4ztXakdTVKjsPyYNyoMctxVRL521tjyha7g9I12y9G25nr5PhCNNJCvJUUL0f0otKr3sayfSHCUL5hcUKHsiU@fJm/8ZmXvBx9klZsxVwlRWVZaUm9xmCW1kr9UWtayVzQGTY0O19UJ@GLOh2ecplJIneld3WZEvLR9KJVLceM4W3abEfUWmiW0G5r0uAm1K8NOX7CxBKgg8v93u2yla5n5qVu5aJhpJXBSvDp8yvlvFgoZBTqQuxUnownThWn6UirWupeP12n9UEz2jONIrt4EujlUqleZnl@2U0XjXGlfdlQinFm0s@U49fDfklpqTUpfEXxyfj4Jk4rDf5yygiRWjpSeGqf80/FWayujhWTb@ZvWbNSB2VXjLaqWnc@WWWHjLgIR/I3RnXQ126ht45WVGh6Ue/26@JIWczrl2b7KjxpsOP2XB7HFE7zRfLJapVjB2E8CYveqMpEla8G5k2jMrvSaXq4ik0F7Vy4kqhSSBuki/XYZYg7P@/mki128lQSQolyZJqeh6r1sk@JClquOJjITHZcHwnXEkwZOrHa6JJpVKTW4HaavUkuG9Sq2xOTymVnrl5lx/PceDZqthZhmF412yXDaNRvzH5xFupdxuVeddhv5grZaz7LcUa8qmTz1bE2bfcm84tIlBoVwjejcvxSGsTG8aKw7F5NtWTtclXMDi8ivq5ymTC7nCk/VeXRU6Vnmr2nuNRuXF/SnUycV5inZdy8GXZog7pITPLnESG@Kg7ZeEuZzKbTfrWuqMVl7boMbI6Hws3zHp3WOtc1s92/EPibixZY@peqUGzcXGqN85uL/rSvUHIYxDdL61fnJaNwkxvfsvNifdmTWN@4ejWvRuNRMdnzzaKTynCai0Y78cllZVbIaXpsUQatP6gtayWhXilT7KTczY99lyLLJvTyqj2L1NPCTaxXnovzSDSXXijDRKLFLK4vz/nrRE8rzietS3ZwTc9vk2NjwrW4eppXxSqVedLCy9zCzDPR/FXs4uZaGMXm/fw0VEzPG51izExWxE4n8jSvz8dCpcCKzcVsHqoVqtemEoku2te34ytohSjFDxbX@bhQjgh9RlrdZvWC2lNaXJqhL@nQvNW@9qkD5aki@Ma1UCGsxfLMosbBzPg2M73sx3qtkdw5z1wkh1Q/wud9TSNWvI093TyVJf1m5ItPQOUkxPrsugwmSc9sNSOLazHZZVftbKLD9QorNn9FpyMXF9NkMRS6LCVLXcpoRCcgLU/z0M1lTg5d19rNyNSXq@QW/WHjtlXPzsuJ2y47qXUas0s8GQvTzFysjuqtZaWwaElCLD@u58UM5Stez41qUhPruXZep2t9sRAZjS/OC@fC9IqfLvKKjxkUW8vZ03QiJC7LMifoSqFuDtN8uJsYhxd8UUs/XbWp5QWXv2SziXZCH0v85ajSMkbGrKOJUjryFF34zPqoJl1Fc/XmjTJqDSsVnc@WQ3FDyI0bk9hta7TozYR8/5ISzeSMlxfnlZipZJYF6aZVvr7sN5glX0tcVgr6gunRhacGMzPpVqJRaw56FV0qjWDg9HVbqpqQQaWYQ/Wa4rRhkZm301f9xMDInjOJ0uWi2pIqPuY6Xx/lQsZM99HDSTWUW6n5y7A4jw/q11cTRs/O@kPfVS1O344y6rxCRc1@uMMZ42RdZLvdNq3l6yvDKCdaPd/VtUwL9dBtPHOxYpu9sNafDruJ7uR89tTtlp967cYFNOeNT4g1yk/U4PrqwoiLSZ7ttzLZUlqdacylPqmLkUlJ7bZCXdHXXeSK86fQFVMYFXtspTJcrTL8pd5RErlJr5zllqNWok2F81WmfxsWtMtW7qlbGE5HfLa04MM36oXhu4lUFtNzPRGPsZHkjDPC7cmk7UukZckXDw@Xw1AmP4vl6L5e71D5qi/bUVXoBfXbGFehjUi/IptGK95s5JP1bCF7UbrK34ilZKPI3dz4utfFbD7djF1eDceRqy5rZOhMeThqhKhRKTvu06aZmEoNqWDkz/XcYng7vp5Me/P4rGR0V8oVN5UGE1bktHGnpMRj6ev2U7TKhPNlOn@7kpVQPLpIUn1e7F/Scn1800lI@Qu6Kw9hAp0D@R/flKc6L@rGMNmBmpdXSjzbqg7a@oU8rAGFcm@q8eIkKY2HQviWqtONRCHeka9EvtqtT@LdnnTTvAzHxekC5q/d3OpKzNHQ6q1uYzhlbmJ5MF0jkadiZzi5nlXaRj2aazdLtQjVfqrnRLaYL5Xat2afrVSZQWFmtuKJizzLTzLjSn6Z6WWK8wLf6lz4Rr5Qs8/PCu20nG/3OWOxvGWSjJ4WR1RsFCtnxBxrzqNtUY9kL4fVMCcX1UX1MqFN6rXLUOYyfy2qY53JXKedT6y9TE6k6HIgptPn7WI3O6DS19ncKNQWDb6u@OZFApYpyNzvfvZRIYKuKwSMmqlSH5HfELePuTh55@AJcvIEfr1959wJ7OyzfZCAaL9fDbRAOX5XC78hfGwVQvY2g/j3APDW4snLvcUA6xwnQG74HA90RH4DQNzZCHXpOPOajI@S8h4BZMeT7KDgfTDyevIvjGP4Ag1@ByWwibxR5yG88X6VNsIRfM4HPqySeTjZ2vL0sNvUYAKhyThFBH76Xb/Apyp8BxnJFnC@WvDu29ZnTnbyA3GGppCTRlyBoItktU/FwJh2UVitiePXZzNQ5EAWZ2PtnV844mg2wcSS5HwPpPhN/@Qu@eA/4lMuJJgSp0yMqT7vjwfqcCYiGWmj3oJfrp4QikZQGMoKfWedZcnGUjQ5GjYO1wRKMvbxUNZRkuS8InxIFjlsEJ9c6UYosD5i6iPykoAfX45dJ6@kFB1NHCm0DvmY3MUeUkqKOZncKQ8nis/nNX0p08f6PDjiO9Z7ok1tT8Q784G8tU8fobLzaj0@/x/7/qoiqqkKP1TdBiI/4Lv9zgk5DMzpQBNO2@5PM4E3VX07RsTyxE12OuLrKLxLzL3IKakOnLnUBLx1tz6VQMY/fY4vH6axyMnrdFzDDx/wERontu/EdgW@UNq0J0v8MfWB8BNvgePX6Y@P7UNheITl9sMHEidZkRYtSDI8OPnESeVVbWlnliyQR6cup1sozzx4b9Xr/xZIB6oHMvmIf61JBzALxGLvDjgC1GRr1GtRhcMlQVnvg@JzfLwn@JQT9NFJc078wfBYbsi5O48mksgpPXA7RTYoOQMDee0TJ0jsnYRfeiOuBGduK@nDaDrRyP5z0KLX5gj@gclHjZP0dc6gMcW/NOxBLGaG5BCNWwAHnvF5bDPOFLabxmkL7PhGXr7C9cH4auT3RIBgntP1JdaN@OUDjK@vkjwfrF8w9SBTtRwrLTLsvKQaXrupgXH44Ga35j5GxA/uBKLIlujJVuoIUnFd30ieQPKEM4dvJA8x7qnxVrIOyfh3Td9IliDZeidyf7oK6dZO/xsAJvbyBHF9NNVHk5Nkj3WgBz4K5NlS2B7k8zmMXYsAshrGao/d/Mg@GgV9tFrHErYd8YL@ScTKAsAi7bE7D37eSAtJxedaeyy52CrT4gn6gr5amO0cCSx@JCWB2sXle4928KMtAqD/gSpFr9Odwq3WXld0R36CMOwMcGsDs8Loxx/fo8wWxF35Yx8c6bNaCPvhbtXQ4tYGj/Wzi5t2tTKt7Ez789hHx2xrN8dHYlMPp1OGNirE6lubfi1KSh/KAMQft6Oxy5MXfdrE3BkP6HitPTZ8tLrF1/kYeiU92COK9Eg/6m2C/LdzlcNyDzk5GJF7G2WBzwnjTl6x01hDB3ahzwB6zc0XcsbvyIzdS39uZb@tNgdAH@nUhDcnlqLlwTQ8swncQx5nteu2TrCQHbqPrXj8c5LSLjLpDWTWeXqPgMA8BRrwyOaocWdMlJSg9U4q6HkmFPETF3ML5HnDJkdZfQuf/gk6F2acPWRP8S9s7aoktIc1r8DX9cb8OnvZ5V5Uz9L0@yt3Z73U7P7kxjSi1/JEpO4TjJLHiEHrg5tO0PPX9dA/jDNfNs23Y@8Ynrd1hdPojiR@iwg@v8HorwrZbhVCD2iH45gEohm@MiSRQwj3D0ob1/pHJ8Zxu7T69psWGKbqZDcd02whdBLAUN7O5bdtrrON6rRPX3w0HePGv7HC8A9bWlIBJvsJta3O8XSuQAbv7dj10VGEI9sp@E12bGHqDmWS6Ni2YAY7@YL8I25mi8mYn9CnB6ra9zgGk20wEAzOCR0A5LeOs1qbVZZ5uSkeirONXjSwT/lwxt0TiPloR5FxBSKw8WnLJibiaEC6zQnuNlv2jWSQ310l6Xg0gqKctw@ws6KlfdDxy3gMvTaBPuzN5Gh8fCYZObnS1vNkJN5RD64sp2DHUNwc1tT61IXj1w2BYc5gor0535K0wfOeVQbrDE/7dMsv21MX6UQKYpt43eiOF6T3/y/uervT6HH9686ncMm2hRYIpH3uPpt/TwkhCfckIQukbU6abQlMktkCw2EghLvtZ9@rn2R7PAMk2d0Xe3oaZsa2JMuyLGs80palZns7AzRW4H/9c@3l@jQar18Hw3V/eE9G9fXcW1P@UNKNbSInfeF3HBRGSnmtTfhcNh9CJDGhkQK24tCfZXXaeUQRzeQ8iUnHhxbLHuIA87nxvn/fI6tfIraMwuiB/85ps1AqTkeTkEs0Io5dp34GP@N4qiX@ikjvGDQ52wwnrpPF9wXydC5nJQtlMZDKCHKcc0BcoiUr3MzXTAbjB0L1edLLKy8q@p3uHYiA7P2U7RQNF0vyLy8yQ49Ya2AFPl6hy75EmRjx2VGgYOskmvM9dR/3ZVzIEz7iCrnX@xSPDwSjpB@GIwg5joKi/TYxQBj/otXerzWbRZ3HRU6s45S7nGPGJ4IcsI7zENhjvDitjnCBMigv0FnAFnw7MXDWv8wjoNVswlSYgZ3CK8QjlB4Uyny30A1bPyfVmSX8uZO@i8DLko7qMSI7CryLm2WdZgXTzFR2WPHiSW50ul0EgjjxByFRXPX7fSJaePEiZgcuwRGD/53FH10C55UlXsoLC@WFRHlRyoWouFaxezeOK226lTJr/4jr/VKZuFp@AdeOok7XTzm6VDEcO3RvPVY3KtImLYgr79qhFKm0BduJgoJT8rcloy8lLxNtrIDb8ksp1/K9oUfeUpmo@zGJH7@eHiCfYzDoTxZTUlocBv0/xP1oS1jDKoRVkuYYbxY7mZTaIaLVSYHUBAkxT9vdnRjKu7LRODxnMrvbHzNF7ZL6I5smQxKQLUysJXPE4RLjfMeMe@CVhPBw8UsHBMOEoCkzc3dN47luPHfAotZLg9YzkUKTE5y6lp7iOzjW/RN/zGRPEmfqrS0vfCGUP0jn5UuLJINY6b7MLGdTUptMxlNfHupOPbKKxLjnaYjLlcRpiB1o9w6awuL05XuQm3A67L20esJVFEZTLPDdlmhOxxXKRnxXDSEKf3n/XH/rHXYGZBX2/QdVgU3d4ZD4XuJjm4kfTSKaAz51cKyi6WjUD3RcNzXjzzmkn@WN3/AxQgzRMRqKXh0fiEr9PK70xzHUqKgagDzDd4ZxQTS9RdpleIKRQZhU601AICdFrzKcc2RiDoO2IZ@8@GqKOK5QwH3a9jlEyMjJ7GHPA6y0omc@LJKu3sj8Hk7IBKKOhxzzEKFWNz3vr9Og@6N6qDZKpT@XS@/LDsuMq7pUfP9B1R0TyRRslMql0m/lD55XDUdz@bQx280B1ocCAObVMRb6TySb/j0y/HoVWjG4YkSmf@SP7/1e0fOafo99wNdT5ghEeRr5EkWZ47ziCdlWiHdP5u4gyivadt1BveAX67PEru1yYI28h2@IRv54EEzkS6PwPuiBgea7qZuw3w9n7IjGJ0vCDzQa@BNiytucSpLEcWk1LWy7cLhY4gaSK3AAv@vwnuNIazaQnRog/D5/AOQhiCIguMgki7lDCeHr9jvBAOK0hABEWYo5YAigrvWmXf9RGjwm4l@kQemO9cLuFJF5O2Zk1kn7hTxXaLr744C0b8xgHhVu5tBOA9w@qrdUq3HQ/lxp1hRdnzUbn@r7tX21d6HaRzVVbZxdcK4qddQ4Ju3SUpXTfXp62m7W987bDXqQqbSoZYYLvMrphap9OWvWWi3VaKr6ydlxnaAR@GbltF2vtfKqflo9PqfF@jCvCII6bbTVcf2k3qZq7UaesZpmXtxONQ7USa1ZPaLbyl79uN6@YIwH9fYpkB0Qtoo6qzTb9er5caWpzs6bZ41WTaFj3n69VT2u1E9q@0XCTzhV7VPttK1aR5Xj41RHG59Pa00Qn@jlXo2orOwd1xgT93O/3qxV2@hQfFUl5hGBx3nVOqtV67iofalRdyrNi7wG2qr99ZwqUaHar5xUDqlzXvYJrtC4VM@btRMQTZxone@12vX2ebumDhuNfeZ1q9b8VK/WWlvKO260mGHnrVpeIfkkoyYYxC0qp@u981ad@VY/bdOacX7WrjdOczTIn4kxRGWFmu4zgxun0ltiUqN5AajgAw9AXn0@qtHzJnjK3KqACy3iWrXtViOExMS22011Wjs8rh/WTqs1FDcA5nO9VcvRgNVbqEAwgfdzhZCec68xTkSXXJKwekZy8zycqn6gKvuf6qBc1yYJaNW1tDDbqkea5zSX172lr9wefYG3@JZPu0IeDxJfbezXyOKT5CyZ@Pk5LTq/J1/eJcpoobGFdKvfgvJa9a3nX09vvwXDmxBbc9tM3mAPots8UhTlkPrzq/dIVmP9opwbrK19@/ap8o32ua1v33L557RMkPFUCx2F9bFaOd3Hftjp8TY/4VtyGbX7Wsd6z0vgZdfX8to6H3Jqfb3n62b4eBGAjZtIJyUgYD1oRv6qsTNUDkp@xZz0FXHGjLSzyLzeDCP6M/wZ38ja4Dwg5SznFtbXsYdlMpD5RFn6CQknBdGZQfgcQHDDKIuR7/@4zZZcdNjyawdVzrThuhPaBt5mc080v/ZvU80L6fZMLL41ZWPFhIM3YdohmCHfaZYpPS7FMfcsK649/skZahgRGYU5QcUfsurTJ9nX0hzxRcVXmNuyocQ5HchJ5Uv9MzZzpY0PW6nnR/a5zC18dY7cNrTeXXK7K/45upIKNMECbL@IJcFcXqmurzttyCpje9JWRqz6O1SaBT1aU7FU3/m8rCNCvoQLdtvTYjwOHlzqSQ0fNisne@cHB6Q5Qe2H33/78/9seTri/njyJS@/F8CD9I7MXbKiZwGZaVzkzJIq2T0HC8lynOw@GD1URGpFM2j8sEMmrY2cKTaC5NcQNxC6GyHDwBBJNjJIEjDOKHyf77/0jLwunZlaALKJrubQm0HngS38DplKLANdiZLZn/OoPeAPYNvpb6a47ZAWIC1i/mA0mZPk0uaC9V7mwAQc4L0Nf1aMKsWMkeNRx5xBEsZAZ3IUBnyDz3datp1RJLsWA435ysPOLYmIl2kqTJIWTrlEKM7CyMxgeRjQky9a3ujyQicHQhFSPVQmLWLjgW1ZMMl7xOesJ4aGfLW7Q0P0@rXFtK3gSM1posT/n0wd484GJkUONKgUYHPyyPLZlrAT@uObnPqHSCqiegPOlpZYfU@Su6w7GsqWCYmu700GGSWw4oQy/GhmcXimyoWpYtmZYNN/xA@G/1/kyRL427ThJOgxt1gPB8Op/0xOMlThFe1emSnBzJwYc46pxdx0H13EYH65A3NnO6aP4T3IiyVigR6duXlwISnFsksYACGHX8Odvwjgy5P4rkM7p488d1/Im/7xsDsYZU1CLrNULMC9yrPNlTdH5HCTk1f4JeWgO0Z@lY8c55F1BjZcpMWu5@pVlBEY78qsc9Dp9bfs9LCznEUTbCibGR6LU0lPLTP5H/QJo3iV6ZnSX2SKrk72ZV@HIKdQQuGbNyBGgfDZJ7fDmm2EcxeELu03Ir2wl1/pVRwZI0kF8rqs2hyeI@rc8J4ZS5GOpYGgHUAJOK96OmfTtT@ZYbnoC3SOIRJDU9lXHMYESLQv0poRRvnmisR1XmRnlnp2U0JeLfXnwx9DZBX2xcVlahQTGaDcEKxFddLhZFD95/U7EyN/B7buJvHXhxxXpSvvK@Ga4507YcFO/1UUc4QszhmsS1qHYi51uj/wMGNkNJgVggf6YVwF3XOT04j2DJyxbpnR/2vlhgCykjoDqzJfh9aJtCkL2c4rY77gSuauvbrAlfYz71CniDh6ggOz2gwCybCbcEhzcbYxfYmwOjh8ukmW02xWvO5MB53hTWcQ9Od86vTv4d1wPRpOo1FxNPcymUzSG4hA4AiRQrRPfPU5GPbCWaT2aDrAkdQ6PW@dJR1/juerKp4vpf6XcKg9xuwtgL9BzKQovJnQ0Phbaq7TbI9jdw/7CbWnhd1aczxAYKoxCxDhHVjL@PD0XB36Q39M9uAZn7lUx0HXH5L6IGOKT2FGd6JpUP0A2FsauzqA7cKenS3lB@zUsb49TyPQ0PIQrSxNRSJ4rNMqwjc/J1F3fILFxQ7H/eoZp9JdONLRgOA0hbEpLs6baT/vIXfj53r7CJtx2Zizb4aWNePrgy9RTKeBOGupM@POcDInpnhp5w2R/ZTvpqg4GBBB9Fazkzd1A2Ql78Ht14@oq8iRrrUAryA0Vf3gHsni2A33nDHic7babRbzbUvHV8xL@jqjOhKj58Wjl0fO0GJe/fYX1fYhu@qs3@nSDku1pmj@/j3ZgXthNEHVk4pSpY1yuVwov4eL9rxVKfJEwH@TQczz6idnjWabGKlD5BvBsGsmmM9Ju@Q0FrGjgNRd1PvvUMimPmnMje/MPJjgJo5vZkveWGQ2MzT23Q7cvdTDKGkOs0sWLvlwzInDEA2KRCgxHQkrgh4gRR8rSWByoOc5dZlOPiZLi6WTo/lxg@@grU9y1cf70O/cmJ@RAvAf@Bm1GvPOoKfD3tOYDPyBpT6YmNW9IxW8dM4zyzDxpZJwvMm/gZVE3Mu5cHo@zkhEyB4wiO67Y9ItnXsSORxhMSGxSGZYN@VsbzrXQT@gOUB0de9CLDiirsxAsAvCzYjm8YjbXDtYkJiWJdkKaHb1woGtKlR5ng0Gp5@Ponk3VGu3tM3GTisa@X6PMyVMR5IKAOVFmuV9WjkkTNxmnCPAWyvxuckxKRukZCHdN@0jdixi/V3LmHumNyRVJrxg@w7begFEPWpNeJIiY1t2yQ47r/CeN8fD3iGBQNscGLEi0B@BGOXxUoqoovFmgeArFpc8wlH1ebzTcQDRkJMRRaNkAWDJW10/WWDAo@/6cqGCCOmOJSAVYtAQI3Gy5DrhA0veoL84d4qgaVnpI3VunrPMPAiQQlN8A6G6DfEXlYuGY/KO0Od3hAuBCx8QkpfgpWuWF2tSLZtAxKm5sQRmYSnM98thFjRM/bKyPrzngG1oxWIhvZBo0CHpRzAi7v5haFQvh5Xrh/KCyfb@th9eI28TaQrChp95Ph5Y9zHvwBKMdksliGAy39S26ZImXX/bZGwXtU3zw99V28Zjsft1KAOlC3ZkLnHMMsVrF08nvsQfPaP4MpNIXgWrI5W9CuTJU9LdAJvRIPWTzKaKZyZO4rj1NeZkk0GiSTnVRBOXbHKdaLLhxZFKU6OLFlD9@E32zNglfCqJR0Dt2AEqeYPOg@xuShyAjt00SBmZiIi3caUFBBUvu8rGtEP1Ky8O0Zx4bS84zC0fweMT35k/ZTjlVSmZ7@DBHN1jNcC1EuVzDgM@zOoO5TQb@MaGf84ZYnS/trnJ0NFUtsNS4CW6Pca3WlkXS25TrY068tYQtSIsbC7qS@YB3tJn6N9bldUICi6xUglhdbUqJMZz6OVL2srKsBg9WPLilZnvHAVHI@iJ/uYjY7IMZLOJeWU0t4Uplwu6m0DhuYBjTJ7E/4zIrpOnWFEc1dCCwYc0ptrI8x9oe8bvmBkErz/WY60fSkxjqz008Zcx5iuzaiR7sbJ2eilZVsdZVSwXHqtsmG35tLLy6tWGWQcfAvSdVHdYdwwnsWadWYLfRMIytlKCCQc7DbuBaKgk2xylK23zSxRwcsgNcflUrzwnlLnuYXoZ8RIrZ0JIss4d0rSrV5LITgDlvEQr8H/VgOO4ozuxV9YrSz097KskwsIy4/6YWNjKZtwfEwup7Az742Jhchla1nL7tFwkRkJYgEOJesfAPiVXB5mCB7fWQ6oWEzS/cmOZ@/3sEmodrap9nd6CqWRZpFOXJHHwz4MMzJoONJoQR2LepR2Nq7i3tMZ1f/g9G5FZ995ukXYzySVBRjOdiACdNhh4jK5ySJltG5DGFieY3jMP5OwmR7R/IxsW3oMia9ftXfLr3gRYs6qUcosGpYneHxO/vZT4wmIWhXiLtbmYH96eLtNU48BTOO6hdsZb8sbXe4Kqdw5Vyd45I5Rk8QpIhWdBKjwD0roDSU/s97Re8uXaGHnq/KdAfP26CIN//kYbKQ2DNG0vgBMb@@BZZ/4UzJdkbK3xmbqOnCqzDWI7@SkYf6RhcF7QO/s2Tj@868Dr9n/@OExn5VjJ2aSsLKHIUrW2SFYeZLHW5v2urmdMJd7bFn9c3wV2J7D29EhLHGPdGEeJ7@xLoLVkVH0LLJ7/5RX8yzvDmpwPQnjCDUPWsvcvTociGCEeJvlUzDZwFFlyH6oLkox4vDSt/Hi3mo5@jISnK5vlnuzJR3H4OE6nMnVNNFZC4swWLlZOZrUy@m3Z9uxJ/GtL8Y/CEdk4N0sJ4PoD@PHFKZVS6bFpmtpaP2stW7qeLfbLtdtSuUmeP8lfL3R9g7qOD9NpUg/9mV79H4Os@2JG4N@w5C@NjKwg8tVSIvGivaOdW2o4HVz7Y@85U11aFPEje6TVkut5a2uq0qUts46MD69Yl9P3@RolzGAIQqSmI7yvieRwJyY3fGS@CHC6bi@cDbl2MQMU7KMd@J2hDpWvF8zbMd5f2Lp5pO/Ex12MIRh2idGR77g/v0tO6p6vS3Ai@RG2bi0fe0g1cGoq8jEmTZbYmtl5ck8rT1cYONaq4VqbaUPFyA5ehr4Vy1zbS2SY55a7wJ5jPT1mEJEQr0KpN7wp0I/L6OZqZk5HlpV2aJ7BymXmlvVyP8Pcmj/X3PovcDI9oJ5zra0HvcBuPqnU0pt87/8B)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))

### Explanation

Bloated/Modular/Core SNUSP code is now this:

```
     |          All 3          ||   Bloated   ||MC|Modular| |                            Core
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>+.--._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
                               \               /  \         /
```

First Bloated SNUSP is separated from Modular/Core with `;`. Then Modular and Core are separated in code tagged MC. When MC is executed we have
this memory layout (current cell is !):

- Core   : [1,  2!]
- Modular: [0, 50!]

So to distinguish them we only need to move data pointer left and use `?` (skip if zero) instruction.

Because we use compacted code to obtain number 50 we can properly exit in Modular with `#` only if current cell value is nonzero.
If `<` is added before `#` then it prints `3131313131424242424253535353536464646464757575757586868686869797979797:8:8:8:8:8`.
Core and Modular code cannot be swapped because Core does not have `#`.
To get rid of this problem with exit value I switched to the SNUSP interpreter in the test driver for Modular SNUSP. So now all 3 SNUSPs are
handled by the interpreter in the test driver.

Last `<` is for Perl 6.

To get rid of blank line above Haskell code I made C++ code Retina-friendly: `q(z++,z++)` → `q(z+=1, z)`.

#### Wierd

Refactored Wierd. In this version `6` is copied from (3,1) to (1,1) and then used to print all the digits. In two places it uses gap jumping ("spark").

```
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x
```

To run it standalone insert

```
x 6
x
```

at the beginning.

#### Emotinomicon and Wierd

Online interpreters for Emotinomicon and Wierd are very slow. Here are their node.js counterparts which are much faster (Emotinomicon is still very slow - 25 sec).

- [Emotinomicon node](https://tio.run/##3Vtbc9s4sn62fgWHVfGQESXxIsmWKDqVeDN1tmrjfZjZJ8ezRZGQBYciGRKM5ePot882LpQIEpKS2qrzcFKJLTS@bjQa3Q2goSzDcv3XX6ORlmfJywonSamtimyjbeK0974owpdhXmQkIy85GtLu798NFTlYVWlEcJYaxHzFKyOtgBaQNS5Nsi6yZy1Fz9ofgP5YFFlh6LRHg78Up2WFlmZEi9EKpyjWTX8FkG9hoRXBP5dPKCIGE2SlQTFMUPpI1jc3N7aFg7B4rDYoJeW982CFAaZUFNg34btPIVkPN@HWSPuhZZtz3sapEVqpaWUNTvfBWgffMhxrdhAE2bt0nlExCYhZN8WsJTFrEOMnN8g3i3v0EBAL9ft@gUhVpFqxM/1ebzTCmzwriLYRPMOnskcnRdtaoBXoa4ULZPw6HDUQv1JWiiLZF5SWgLvXP1fxtRfDT2TbutVsTuTmTG7GUtNx5eaV3IykpuvIolrNabMZO6tmMwp5072aTeoP0/rDlfjgCIqHlvWHqP4Q1h/204noKLPW7EK5ieTpeHLzWm7KlnFly9itptB56oWfqxWyV3Kv3HTGclPW2ZGVdGUl7VZT1tleyqJkT3BkT3Bk48gLhFxZSVtqRletCcqO4cie4EzlpqykKyvpykq6Mq8r83oyryfzevIEvdYEZd925Sl48hQ8WQ1PVmPcmoK8KK7sSJ7sOZ6shiepEU3l5XZlV3FlV/FksCer4cWyZHl9XdlWrmwrTwZ7shoekiVPmiG5OjgDb7py05ObY7nZEjWVm1dyU5pvLAdsLPtzLOeuWDih68hTi1byiKGc00Rs0nin@WpyJTc9kccmdYqbcB1cm0rbZwnXHs/kpMHGWrr6g8@yPNrmSZiGdOPkuT6vyrVmQ/bXyBppJQmjL8DKqI6S6iqpnpI6VlInSupUSb1SUq@V1Jl6FkcmZ3foYRwDKdfIc6ahBLHdWsvSfX9ZLUkRRuQkKMbfcIxOQjZVQnCevJwEkfALgjbSonVIB0WFFsIBJs0rYmlsBph0JpblpRamsZZVBHAlGyBb8X7KvpcF4CxHqZZkWQ6foyQrUd2IqzzBUUiQxE47Cqov/BP6NvsK9A0VpaSKdudrueC4a8xRMFlMUzYTmMMGpqbVQrIiZiqCs4IFUoJrZZrGqm2UZI/aMgSuD1T0nUXHzHH6CGOC3FT7UGsjzDa4axG@333XjHBZZkkFw3wLkwqZLYjb5vHahHGbcDdyOxSvQxm3KX92uP7scP3Z5iq/FuT@7qFFjZYqapFl5H780O1YwfIXCikIJyopVRp3yXd9p00ZNCifBPGT9gZWx9hkcZVUZcfYf3as3aGMO5QVXmZpGEW4q1VSRWEpyLSd4/oT2pPWuM2UGnemZiyiLEY34GP/RtBejFizrTF0t8COfRyNOro7dpP0VG1ybYnWGMLjDk7uUbbZQKgIwK1FMTR0SkRY9DcwNCHctoRTyCGHUI1onLQY26v2xhWWQZBQtAIQcENLq80SRECg3tuWs59WI@PQHBMKHHQv0SOAv1YZoYmhgKCkQQ3oFilKEGxNXEQd1iAEFTjiGQ@I2v/Bv7298CYEzcPiRavSbpqVWJouCCbOChw24uWDpb2vF8zSMOQnegclRUXWL4Lrva9lIL14xiUSJJqyyi84hzvslrSXyO@I6UCtRgKm8uKsWibo3wr9FNLQFkU0EarGhhAWIvdOgVOCHoVXQHzfmfVJY5Nl@@vk3669W/j5mzi/7Zuu3PTk5lhuTuTmVG5eyc1rqga75kZZusKPxiv3yrm@xI@1g@YFinAJR6H5dEyv0HVJgd@F8f8iozBfi6AYgqNujEOVgAT3D1Ya0Ku/rls44FdnP13U1QLffK2x4b6EMEj98MaGLkpeB3gIAY62/1wZxRBOFjwYjNRK@6Fp@nhlDJxfgmBtvuo6/EaXl2RILW8goY3JRxdUfL9@MIE3CAeOvyxQ@GUXDgYWrTCEl5cGChA1BOzqMBrNBu@JkZqmuUv7/R2vIhwdhuzYeu69B9aUGXZPEOuNNmCWhhHDApP1BhEcfdxGKGe1mjTcIPO1d0HLK0PaCOgPv7c7sO0TOSgISFraWdj004WodsAEexc73hMEUpd96Fl4zQ7BIlqNIQaO2W82XVNSJsYlnJdfjC0VJri3w02YG/vyE8xHdNwxtwLLsTMELKxpfv8Odsx@52tr7mThHzcZwWm2wbAyBk3MdBBqym2wd0BG7gwIE4M5crfbuxEywU5CFTQEvTExdB2G3FsBUStQQu2cT4HtPy22tdc@9fu1bF5ywyX7bWzvnx5M1sX0SwJKqLkodcvGi9AwzOFga2yt@yfLeahdjrMz4FM/SNgC0uXY8emC64NP6XrdgizLPKnuBNt9ottWAD6YlHQSexOWBOXMRha2@KnygK@n0qIoLLe9xw9mEEwn5gEb1GNdXKCkPtjy0KBwFkS3gINA4lPbaQzHhhjBzp/CgRIN6dFAjb8onzGJ1kpduKIXET3W2vPG0Czw9hnMsEEUC3b/gHdO4B0F3j2BdxV47wTeU@DHJ/BjBX5yAj9R4Kcn8FMF/uoE/kqBvz6Bv1bgZyfwM9V6nVpgR7nCJ5fYVrK4cxpMy0AwZrlhWmGz5bdFwm3YCK2lSpj308Lqq/MxieOflsjv2cfkTX5aXn0pPyZxyiTS02iQF9kmhzBu5FjIKbRLpES6KzXkwx7js9zAIJB7P4YQ9818fnw5kZw46BbSUe1qHmcRe1wYPiLykd@PP7z8PTZ0caY2Ib2kqPifPz79ox/w3WhIH11uhWxDbF0NAzU2MXNYINgFI2SMPqejR0tfLIsbXaHIbM4aPOmCpHsuTxx/nAeR1vgmEsORYB04viAdtiQM@wPr9AeDpz0LFVpX6QO2/5gM1O/7HUQoIQaDGrETv3HwJEic0kmJ9pw/Bh1xmMIqFHl0H5UM3umu86wocqggPK7ugpOr4Tc2b4ttlE@LO7Z1C@0abKbfHI/vrLxb7MxfFFrwWDwaLexFKs@eDSm2VBvLREynCfxwUiy/SI/2nz@oxEoJfyDNtoOVkj0TGy5LyUIKJinju29PjyCle@802JNS/fgMWMryDejIVYDdY2BPAfaOgccK8Hh@bvGVp4TJWTbVYcGbnmVTnRm8q7Nszkip5vUPMCoVnf0Ao0rVsd1hZJW3M045djpstDJ3jsvtcLHK3Tm2Yw7SdxTg8RHwQAWenMmsb07GxFjtHq51Zj5q9/DOsamdY3yOTXKNw@XyNNdE8gtWsjzH0T0G5lgB6x7wkQLVPdbna5W0bjqgibpBU6o6UXE59lm@7nqjbX6WS73cjm2dY7ye40Dy4C5kxhz4VnLg7X2j9aA8YN0qLi7Sissymqc@1Xl@emxzeKPYHKaKLMCKd6oQm3rz0dufOk82LfF2pMHpOEJlOSxJDOjhc4EJko4yh3qI6Wujt/T23w@0phSgNu/Px5hhsI721D33V3hSVKg7wenPHJcDXe9KuJqT4uW1cx/wjx/jKQ4O73DkgpO/fOCnaXLXvUV24xHBGdDQsa66c0pxsi/MnUkgs2vmy9KRzHovte6OJeq7d@/nHxQiZ3MMJ/LuHdee15cCoY4aJrl1vEx@@8GpOLZLB/jl/Aj8jL0Jt9I8Nzg9eTDlW7QUOm9hVbYDYDTNPv3ZGGvHy1sXo7egU7@P9xU2fpspEfkDbxA4m0HrV5ZrW8dKWO3C0t6IQp7WjJO6WMkQosjU7Nf/lqXoF14R3L0dsfrbaHQoodmq8Q/FQhzYvnaYC3yGOweIOlmD83utYhj0sSpob/Rf/OnhlWbUiSYsHr8JnbRFoLkmmEqDP9LU/1WGj2iupbSOiBp11wGlDJ9KbbHCCaK3WsZby0ZbuODTCO2JIjiAaMVaC7Tm8Pfug/gW3apsftNuxb5eR@mRKGCWcB8L499AzO8vaWTU8izt14qsrin6v7ILcNejBUezHO2lEwX020M1usrjkKAPLwTdwhER0tlro84aGzl/t8jqp4@vQS6MbhXWxn9ew0yMdPGVPpjkze0rBS@h9ZHiJphM3Nn08rJYBJOp58wuLxl@o8Ybm8vpeOK4ZkDRrm2@ZjwgDaO4hHj3zMXCsc0@4FirP51MvKm5o8FSQ8HV0sFg16LtxIuHlkEAHLXSkloilTYDWEC6SkOUUhMyn@cXc/NQCz9udTrFjrxYKWXX66yG32PAMI4/fgOZ/8AQdiDG0L@glyrXrRbDSXycPacqDlYzqwjJ0uPOU1ZLXUCzj/Qt6CiyyEiNLCB19CDt/T0lqKDb2L74Rb0M5Eg2YS@H90W/T98AijcBax9sY9ESp9@DBAbuyxLTJqfvjNOxNZ2Ix0ecaZTkTC3nypp61nRqTa8eWFe5YV2QdF3Hcl3L9QRPlnMe13I8yxlbzsSajK0J/JxaE5DiWLMra3YNwzuCIyaMY@JYE9eawCi2NXWtGXDbtdCIJEwosM2sybU1mVmzGZ0B/KNJ45Bc3bGPFxPHx/wRJsvFwx5/M2rkYLxw3BoVkwYKLNLrvin5LMz5sircIUowfdRuLEhHhPBO9iVj8VrRLWJauH69WlZNr4gg3xEkHAOiiunB9qBlJa06EqQYPmP@OUrCsrzj6daAVd4/kmDzJrDf6fz7zmFKNH2u65AKcNaBZHVfuWn3bcK07sw6ssEbRB/YuNUHcRPWvbDA7W665rxXh63mCes@e5JsfvXuHj8Ega7ppjRLOAbrWpVCEw6OKNa5FX5kzXq8pro9FY887fPFlJ8H69c7vtolShCT@zsJC2LJtI9pPFCh2IPufjmZ1B9SBBTeDp8ynNa6KBIff7NUWmKTVSXKvtHHfNkaRwenqyAf8BdlDo7AViH4rCewn6PP@o3el6fU1xcjCryhxW@j7o37uq/pfVGwFbTGLcWZmmcQHkWYrKLel11EYLmjvNMbfjFX4vaWOj53iGxUwuzDPEdpfAt7dmwsK5o7mt9@eKS2pUF7GMWog5tk1Mek52mRHsR7LQmXCTqRAFi/vkevi1PYggEN@l85@EM0DC82gr5jmuw/gsD9WH4fD2kq4t@xaL2tAjd9XQVnDY4OuYYh4ZR/8A/O9P273jC6TiH7uA2k3LQ@n5vWJ3LT@lRuWp/ITevTuWl9LDeJsxBsrTtT@TgFayQ5DN8JLthCSh0AbH65gO9VhxWr9yy@8OfW3Tq2ejRJkOL/i/Vrc8T03vCTjs69nMSnLEn/c1O9wrG/49aL6f4jbb7ctnXnYXAZJacd5erQQNGFHLU3KZ1J5U3MmdgVFS5UG0jyWpgk@6//8vyBTm14zYClsvgdBS6EYUnYGOYrGnLRQplGFwzc0odqyA5jRweExEmT67H9WpFXQZ4y29Lj7V9//Qc) (local)
- [Wierd node](https://tio.run/##5T1rd9s2lp/rX4FquyMq0cNOp52uXWc3tdOpd9okJ0629cnkNDQJSWwoQkNStjWtf3v3PgACJEFJTtPMzG7OTG2TwAVw3/fiArwMi/mvv8porkTvk4OeeCiuE5nHo5@yaPxTsReFJTxaqnS9l6lY1l7S419//VJ8jw/FMlezPFyIucylePjrVZiLWEWrhcxKcSxe/Xw79P3v9R42XCt1CY1@vj3a29ubfKh/MNS9PXFPvJgnhZgmqRTwcxnmpVBTmhIu8krmRaIysT/@E7Z9dBUmaXgJbae5gsWW5bI4nExmSTlfXY4jtZgAygq5lhMNYNIaIclEOZdiubpMkwhwtAiTbCzEuZQEDqCtMngjs0KOVT6biKkCVMoSBi7GAG0CGEqmIrhOslhdjxl3x8dilcVymmQyHtTwyWt8JAIYVOWyTKIwTdcDaH6psEsME8uLcgTT4l/UqhRFGUZveTBaxzn@DRCnqywqAR3BQPy8J@BfCSsb/1iUAFkPaJ@WagnP9mEO1bMlPWpBwX@4JKcfLGjffY3/YParPLMLPare3la/ITvlslilyHXO7F5VsF/bbna80bE4sM/1QAyHH9/WlrEq5u46rsJ0Jd3ZWsD3a4D9EwJQBMEzUpH8XXZhTM@yglPvjnTHf/fEWSnzsJRCAS8LCf9Z83BCMScSsYcCZ1sqcanKUi3GpjOMjEwbCmSbS@SC63kSzUUZvpWFKK8VSky4kDBGcWg6LVWR4HRFsE@URNAgUzTQQIRZzBMwg0zseoHXZRjVkAu/uKtGaQiQyjBIRWJcPT14CPyGv4xGTeYBMA5/jbDRsEYPePB60GSpNjZP8/C6EDKVqNkKXBbikAUEZCgUMTRIspmIVFbKm7LC5A0tfC1CEJUozK7CApqoPE4yIA7MBd9eJ3E5p9/mMpnNS9PX6bPKEh52IcNilVdIBCUjQU1MQ2T9ZLHkCYZEhp9WRQnsAnKTFzjdhQBAOLmh6Qwzv0xZ5vnBU@CTPAGVn6AuXMHMgOWBPXB1DCJOplPQ9VmZrj2ExHaPeQ4uMaPyZijgf@uhiGSafo/r5V@/oQUPCbMu7aDHGFRnel6uUxSFHs2zd9Rq8ALWE2DvcanOyxxIEAx4rMHRRlruSL9qvkQfO@VNxCFuJYbG9h1oOuGBWmjyIshFDUrBJwhGy0FDz2hZCgxUERDPNxGM/z5p0oxnsD8kobrnEqjWr/1vE1Ud4dqZJCoj3UPY1UJXUeS5RPXIrXUT4FD8K5MSLVucQHs038UHoCL3dYlIT3akI@Ab@nKX8UyWmimC/oO4P9BYMm1ZS9QMCz5mlVHTiXs182rX3vAX6syAAoVjfxUWMoUGKHQAzBG5SuwUSbeDxfuit7wRC5WpYhlGstnHToD6a/yS5Pb@qzcY08pcHWylnDFjls4/HXIeNVtW2NC/uEzs4AWnEaUyzJ/LqAz2iefdsYZ1eING18142hVHdbl1dMImRVBJEPzvA/rM/5@c5kyoy5@AL8B2LsEZBN2DhiG0/g3qkDjJJetXmGShFuBQIVlhdmiR6XcEtgjX4hJ9Ljmq1FKYiiBkrL0Il3IoYNIhuElovFpjcnyFoAq1yiPwN6k1uGA1gCdAC9CLYcZDi6BYgeIK0YWjgZ6l4XqayDQeDzgwsPO/gp8IMwKSLMMs0arVrHYIA7OuXeUFtAPBEL23mbpmlxChXcMik7JfgNCFoIB7Q3EJ0QSZqGkYJWlSrkk3i0yViI1VIWMkD8/EwAXeB/LijC9XSUqhSUEejbhK5PVQJGPAblIKHBuGggmA2mf3BgGB8pbptGY5AtfOgrM6VzGhT7PVIokLYuBvXnz3LTlGCCe4zsPlC6cHk7SQ@u@CbAYuQVyuCQ5OT0RpWBSAumBpMD1EaCURmEkH9rCMxgNR89kMUPKwLsMC@PwyVWACGS1GBhBWpFKAI2bJlczM2NZHCktgIMA7DAMsr5lI81ZKGmiWS@iYTBlbKF9IDy0JTth3wgTpivsSsJPuS/brYvgRr1vREJq3m4aHsoZn68azGBvGzZYxNo3XR77gxxM2RanKtsVNGdDKWWUwoPVwjHCjQ4P10EzK/NJ0Jukp2OsfdonSbvx9L3bpu/ZFh41xbzZhvdmzNmqbXg5taj2T4huSbbd3m@TuzJGix0hT8Yc/WGoeW3rW4IfxVZhFncTTq7p/bGC3WKp65YOeKwiJ5AnKFUQ0cmsyQs99vzn10UHTa7LMe3Dk8OzIcdJuwYMtZAv4wTsD37877P0dQb/DtDfMev9uoPfvAHp0x2mPDt4Z@P47AN/fFfjoXaY@2hXnNeidYqFWYCHz6HeVjt951R@QYu@Z135HGfkdJftD6aP3rUfvLh2nEt2mWoQf8yN3FHCFwQUzbzAf6Z2DX@CCQT1eNlBGx@KPn3WnJjmsqsIItM9HFG/MlAjRJUeneh5mMwhHyAFM17X0xUJdyfqy0jL0G1165bGrCOJbOa25g@ECl9dUHPy0GXyZp61k@Q0unt92DPtcx/nve9z7G8bNAcWbtOPH1Apd/sGGXQvXScK26Atq/9PnZV7nSSk3bjv4h26sjEZarqyny2C6EnJfA/NQWITBTQEhUDMznCZvfZn8KnhyJoyRVTPx5eZ2OW1ZPfjlF9H7t8/2p9PP9nstrPW/hPgWAkNsedzDnYlZjhtah6Iv7jtQ74t@7yE8auYtKRSEl19OEM7D/qb16yjyjhjYlNvdkALflPzeCUGmE2W0Ng1kM0h7ex924/WuaaTP/7X3XrtzNDPgI1wyyWDhhN5VmuaOu66LJMOQsKFtzKuLrlfhzQ/dr7p6/WhSF7XXDfk5lyXh3LTlrUfEK6WFbDpKEKlMN24GDVjcOceC@nFAfcNsTZwMQMJSXIdVvww3OAWqylICsRXlPeagrd9UU3wjUPsNgBlKJZLSI7kQHZ9WS7Pqtr3DaxFwtUNqwiLl6SVmuDhnRAuFRZCo6hxTA1vXIM2m66W0KEl485EQAThoLd6zNEBhM2XT1MhXjZ3zm/v9Yf/@2tk3RxG4ajJ@bTtaz7@FlKsujHxPxi2krIymPZKnQsoTBa@Z2NAyyWamo0tX6hIyPuYhZy8LuQizMoloQwfcF@l2rhGAoGPfI0zCri4L@bcVbl9arsMWpiv4bLy5isRxF29Zul/U6eghB3BiO4PWsutIlbcSPVVNiwYpaAU1cqBpsI9rNGn6o4QTWaM4jPX6yFN64Su4qLxw1jzNSdyIL61iGtR01M2RBwgpojaQh1ZPDWoqywuEFF0TyNqZycWgphLX/pl4gdiZXAxqGnLtL/NAXPoLPCzzfwsOBCslTpjHSnJKdrWMQ6INvK4MAtXtoB9yqiwfo3Fjb2SBm/0xysFlWEZzZHsCXfD29gKNhpxOkygB5jYAQEYymQPjTyEegd6451CoIVV9APHhR7RKYSpf0djBwM/Kp0lerv/F@fmutHtukUN0YuqIAFhrApwhfpgAn3DNDG4XlDl4qjK2dReA7wwrsnAPo1gtlyq3WwHoWAqzjT/QFlJYI4ksore674HjIoviHrJA/0pvSxiSgPoC1UZ7U0sgrd1BD84yPbcoLKQmNzPTYiHjBBYFM2OmWOOWA7GU6c2cpUcocD@pyRMtztmY1vX7Llv8ly0@zAY/pl1SRIYjyVweaHKXrTyiWoBimSZlADzciNyxGaYZwKUt5FlWYunFq/3XQ3Gw72m5brY88LV8L5r2vWnb96Zx35vW7arYOsHtfXaUMBqrqrZq3mebd6kqYCO/tjzwfxQn@9d9HuUK@DlE/V2G2QzEMEe/Rv8JEVELDUOwOLag7Onp08NKJylAYG43iwuf20wDPjfgaxtMMdgBxAr99wL@C2uk/140Exgxsk0rc1fJKMoKgjhC9joGPYvYuI/bT/Dk/v1mv1rfG@77wxEKyzHNAX71d3LtmrZjxoGmP8UIx2yIaN2U1P/SWcufRZjKvAx6TWwFPVoGlocMULOfmRo@Gfdgbbe@XU5dt8LUdLC9HdOTiThRK/AmwrRQ6C4QI1wnWBhlTI72iOcyelu4HemdqQoAq/Q9AYLAZBoWaCkU1R6AOsut12L4ZQMpcYpeGr4T/Rq0s4HKURd9upwzBdFjVZVBIYZfd3C9BzfT1R4L8E8SrA0aMmohuqFKoeDR@cnZGar4qi5tHoJngFW06MAkC4pxBDZGT083/5RyGLMMyFONWlX5TtG3yApA1gIQDw2pPGCIG/zF3FAopAKUMJ9RYb5T5MsVINpPiSK5LKno18yKKl3YaSq4CkG7AFwf41aIcppS48n1W1dLhTXVYVwLwIjD9CgenZKqeqaVqclYHrorbvqXaaPggJ6tPc6@g7SNZXG1hk46z8d8VG1H4Pqi36VduhPDTZWxqXt0Bw3UFsGEt0ISULmM03Eqs1k5h0dtsSIXCTrolki2R2WQeNwUvfa/Zt7FN0lTPQfZb0in3ekxIPMWyE4s1cKSIAXWSdc1ngHieRR4etOaRlec4ImMuqzxicquQO83dIeghAWpiRFpBo1bIR6jks3VdRUpFFS@g6pEKwgZG33dVisfRDtY0daVuTUtEbZUmwiA7XiBg5rKAECRNMlZPnXh6AitUk0CplkG7GbcV4va@ZIN6kFn5Xu9968NrGRulr21ybM5NrBy8LyGkA63qOvGvFsmsnJBtZ2snMpOY4lAsW7GEY2aszPotJp2K@WYoYjeX7OeL7A2KTJofIeTKiYKsKGZ9FjeLadU5rmUvnMqbEzseRRBcoICWsGpuJmb2AMTVDZnUq2VtbOCbRKKlZ9kvQTckDAyJTOsgCZpCvMyichJV3nsNYZ3OB1zd@b6jSy0IadTSy5zEmdLemZDJmjgNYYY2SWZydK0ZMYcCMNDQG5Oyj@qbv7xJvn3tN9i7lkGitZ@ia/d7S7hCAMb3NX@t8XuURamaqZWdHwiwML0BNa7CJcocIbTwlSkGESGM1k4UuAIbDOUrLQJBwxMy1XhaPaQoss0wUOIehh9Dop8SBQoq5JiZ1/AAohlUeIJKpSlll6oIuHmKMbmoX4AIFZqg/oiBkNHVdDxraFj44xSaA6HcQBij4t9KRYApScztLFrBT9wYSbzZxKGaupuSjhoxH2v5AotIJcqc1rx9GZyimfJ2FRXGcGA9d61yt9y9nABTYCKajotZGlzdKb9y0JOVykfcLlS6RXXmqOyJUUUrkq1CEtA2NLZpzvjDFll3yl1WJ@Y9SmwlnyFvgpt2vLhnGQ2h1Xnc6V8iRdEXa0apSifTYf4gEY5veEfawpq6S/4sW6mEahl04brh26hkmm79rVde9rimK22/NDXdu1r24Dr19pgS2kOTe2NzxHGHbS4BnXT1OYa1E2nVmfkWyeaNQ@q0eVUH64bbPeVNZQ7eMuPwMksqOqd3T5i/GSxWpC2XY5x2vjnABaknwAH8C66I0oqilZLFPwgU9lIbxiMqBlQAtm8MPne2k40uQF4kD3MpU22d3XAzBAeC9A7gdN6WOduXjoiXhBwSuGDUgUtV@K5CDyAC02ppIkVwxFykl4YjExTcI@F8nZHNQetTVDngGKE@ZAIZkUCHkUFX61KfEDnOP17xN9xAnNrVTq5CIaGNQCcw9wOAH0KLwDOke4yg4uuGVzsOIOL7s2dKuMhstXiEpNbU8tVDj9IYMQqOerH6WO0Ad0HBbZk5Tsy/x1n5NuVmN5mdrxRTVkcbM@q3wU1691Qc7ELai66UXPxe6DmwkHNRQdq/qnvrfjiX7t2Cj17TJQDf5GXciOjFWYHgkkIBiHEXyfGdRngFQMlKEpz5k0WCp1WhGTuJ9EtVO7zcmCwaTJb5SFvcQiq/qMqEnQU1ZQPX2VXMktkhue4rq3WRw9Yp4Z16cmPtTF/HGJIi0hUq9ncHr0CokXgDAEfzkHt43ZrHC5LohW6mguyBWgmqgOB4KH1NOieOT1HJQQLVZSMRM7LFkM9Bp5sSsI0@TsIDO/mRhBJkicM7iUGu9q/pJOKtPss3mCnNybFVMOMBs@GMhSnT7@rMkDEikWBO9z3iGBvlmEm0xM@0yfzN4aPagCHFP9CO3P4j/1Q1it7vNX88szwQsE4R8uGq8A1AaLC5VLSfSZEBUwrmzHNub09NpmHGmUjjD8kSc3lqgTyF2YvnIehaSJrrXjNU3NbRkkgQPRH@Fde2j/U0v4uq98xh21@RwqW7gRStMzVkDrFFuONDbp@aYl@AW61u8xk52UY4IXCPX@AeFIJzFDjh8uZ6FxipSJsK0Ke0iWtezr@mMIrRdcg6FqEQ57wAuUAeIokTlqEIBvhkbsy4WsU@IVcghpnAPXulNXnKIgYUwMh3eRstZh8oCyDwgGEsCgGcc5iDnVCEfgi044U787aKQYJpjDhtyvmqUqemKexP@ih2Ap4SQwMeEdflDgS3rJWWyYRbdCozGDsTZwUGCS9qY4BT8NiDoAH9NccVJ4QF1ifQ64ZTg1lkw6ppgoEZqT0vJZ5coXzBS8@QTUw1CdVw8we7RQ84dxVj1ooDYK4GkiPlO0OgDGpA7hVUbHEm7HmwHPE5hsL6kgrGURmfiVjW9y5XOVLWJqZ0oWFew8U2r0aGniIogF76JxctiyLwFYFZfYSvvMhp@s7cGf/OjPkXkvWf1gJWH8FVJakLLJSK3WybK6A0elofHOOpKS7k9bk4CwlqyyjRb5WJlUZcmqhP1WqP9RJR/eksLxBZMTm2h3PmpgAVj9FYE/ffq2UfiDECWhqTPvPJcNgvQU4KlSUkCbUTzCFiZ35OC/2TImhI7zFCznQVvpodY8CAxGVrWNiQPOQcgKXUmYMSIMFzGZRuor5pDooKZYHulQDj5qYfAUjXOtOo2ZJ1Y@rZQJKMcPjWSgaJ40DPuP9NwiDuJ6Y0GxwDqZAA6kW/BwmhXEP2VHc4zZlwxblo1ymhDTgyUK@lSDVpHZIt/HmCsNqjjfeAZ9EowRrk7OyMKZVuOKGGx88ae016F2WBD2E0sWqOb/jGGnhw2wTsVMHo/rQAvA8KMIpKElUamEOUTMg2RoIUjZVVg5foeqAsTLQ0yCuQ4bmMSNYTG1KFlgBVsg6y5zs9lD00TL0SU8XGsEUlia24kGXI4TrBqq1@kB3SGPcsQEMi0MNupRIu8nSMpGRR0r8ocEyGTTM65F/hpef5auoxKuVMHLPDI5JQKkIxsQoGgyq1QoKuUvkONzgNpl2HDSdn5Mpoxuw2ADRn0NnswIpkVA1hwVJaVB5U47A5VTo4DDlSR7Qf6E67@rIviWIJ5jCxND5i6fPnj0@5Y1fqudwlR@VTct8QbdSxcAqdJnCoOr97NHLc@p8cCTavckKhDEXMwKRJ/kK2A39oiVzE8hZboE9f/nkydmTPwO0B0d@YKssM/li7PDVt09P/kLDf@rvcB1y4QQK@4It33JVNmPXukt6SKQ3/ivu5Gh6KHDE2E0xfqYrZlXKVdfdxoqTOckVF58OMWPETm3DXWVHoJ9bIwymqUrNEuIOMeY1W7ToY9v8eII3Z0DEpm/nqHlZbFtsapYYZHdYmiH9wCbdFz9E01mrOC4G3UrHTff3G/VrzL7HhhEbbysf31NWR/M71909WyhUJzCdjev09R7AZMJUqdC38hk@aB7AnEza4MYcaJzMkzQOLKxBV3E8QkAieaeBL7CWVLfZBIMW7z9MSmqAodDvm7ZfPadSWv@q3YEzX3Ze46qpX/Y@@kiP8fNt/b4qg2tzH@iY5cBcNdaPkyu3frZ9rVntFU7gMSrqb0CNNvScZh4sYwSV@4gedqSBqj7Sl/em8V/1yW7geUIH3mszSjPx7WDdM@WvWHW451S908P2l6ZtF8a4ga/o2Jko9NcWWFfq7A/GpXqJDU5CPGwM69INCkzcBAcNeDwKSDtwPR0BPXbBe9vScczqlq7eZ3LRKFRgD8UVIe7pH1plRAEs@2tQXXerU/rIc6md0SeveKlYz89dfQcCWq@alHwr18iWr3oU@PeGoofGjX9K@kkC2Ht9tLHWCsFsqrSyDBNg01dJ/WbK2pR0BqGbWcgEurzCPcblekl3luV4MrzXeg0uQH2XyjwPcWvpwX77jdnbP/C8A0ryCfTjDZL3iT19B8bj61wtAu7uKTH7RFsicFZg3LN4@3a9hg70Cjyb5uYtkDXo3tJy2KHNya251jlwzKmcY40SB5RmPoLou81IgQRG5VnWOC3WvMlRY4Rb4csjz6vdKFFl3HmDm1nVd5uBdgKvZZLH6MjiplmiA3NM5/xnB6JXGV1uFdy5HLc6fG1if70augaMTk6i30Hh1N9WSe5uPPeJAP1q35rp0nX@U3PgVoQbR4euHkXhGPGvfGoIkVMd7bDPh1Xt7w5mmDXXoTinnGL7nAJoyHP2I/wErYipPa/jyvfquCJAg6wLSs134zCg8VJHOefkkfquTbbvu3Z6qMQUA71j6x@5kyBniN5jsQ3Kct/rEnlXsN0DdetNq1GIUfsd7hsD0nHJ0R25l/L77YxqPdPrZFZrlebaScfkA@U3qpoUk0vmgJlyqYeNso@ReIO4e0NBexYnUWhO13bHgmOnM6FkS@/OaMwncBtYwhyX4DjnSe1gxOM8V3lvcHR3SaK0fYco4VZalyzVGblhLCpBsyofmwyE5@E4TgrM7qJBKHO3cs0HBcOH9jMXxhSYYAsQ5QGiuoD4JbeBmhZmavazfuPcpr7VbDvt@cbTm13aZ4dLkp0Bj3E36Ez/HXjnae1Xx2i3Q8codClPnfZ4B65V3fpfLXfkWbV8Hyy7A7t9IJ61wuNn2e5PDnj9wU4z1@DmHb5k4PLW7sxMp7oqNmwAGmxi384TgVs56znvSnpZ67nOLmzgrW5/oZ74/P/Ddi2kEUc1uYTZbGPg0s57Uaej7hMphblEyvYaeK@w2jZDbXhNUnCz5aWSjQ94gVAPN7vRuYlKvEC7KuxNQ/htHixzQCdenW2ydkNdcGAWyH9h0ox/@eWXKt1I/ACxsZoGkc0haocTvamaL1g1cSNwLGliTH21PosdMBpfVUI7lkvKJ1TgenaDaPxT0bPX7fdsBW7H89G8XKQjvKSq0YIvEG485E@81J/pJPhoGuJF0OvmQMQJo0WYhbPW7LjW2X1J73QehA7fKX1trE4O@PIiiI6uvMhkgo1xihtyHUWUJ8uymU1sdHqVvK5eU0hW5HisjXkGD@HCLKDNUb2RyppnEX1B8/37ep0fH7ursYFWK2PHmHuuVFlx49h5BozZH48ncjbpezprbjEJWd3dfdrOnHzsvvbH8w2wtLOEgcppctVi5u6eOhuIe1eP0mSG6aR@Kqdlvxnz13PuEGGMRjr40TVeINi6vILegY1qdKGjJcD5zxQ5mTtN2LTfMM321Q8c3JzqyTgjPctlYCA2Bqp30sPFFYh@kuHpvRHHmTt0xU8KnPOHgXqfL296O3TBAb4xX0TQndqciCj30rxjYbbDnRbV6oYHI/G7VBX6Ma7f0mcbV1XzP1@G2rhR96Ho0ZdFDnue7DkpRQ9x@eMeNSh/3N/HJE7zko6qy7ew@q9AOb11eg12niLl@rxTpBD6MSu0CgBetEhddhjst03s6arsmpmiV82pIft0DmS7aKraexwFZV7CFvO0uuBl@Gh8@3Sr/bbWKDtfh4uEjoL3q49wbOtmdjT6QPF/39Z4kWSVrPUf7C9v@ncjRQuzMk5KWmON4I@gZ@A4OAefA0d@0WRI7ruT5qg19WiMttolbeyUtPiUs1abpQI49s79qk8zQUdfE7Svx9RVb1XQ70feM@kIudE1oOatHV1zxV01l@ocB@5x/Q9oulYP/jJAtkpBAurqtQ0dk8cnMk1Pq28PBZVzPxSfNzpEDLptg5slCq5dbX@DqfIBcfqH4MkOYSbtZqTeWJfpRq7Ca7evdI1uXf3dbmqFANtOJvbvuq1vsrex9uaoHLmPG4x8gcolqGh3Tv2@427BYNCFzj7zdv9QM3l7Af15EsvTFfr3j6EJtHxlrN5rT2sdCdY7RFwK4GuPpY4wx7/INTTs03c0wUnue1rWKd/fRvq@yk5VJqFdp19qma0WjleHLwgj9BGmHe6zGXSpAQ4Pig204xbn4E1HNSeNnwQae2BknnHdSm8oXr326cNlTXypccUCDWeokyEKGhQZFFDnzsxHPFnyKC6Ws240u/kQ3ADCc1thIXWdLIRj/Nm8WnlTS1YXdPcJMzhuRL18/m3gxAX3RTY46urJPBHsQs0GusI4Dvpz0F9qfN1vvWWkuQ10uqhRADGZVAHapYrXtV1S51Nwt3jzcBW6@9W3U7lmk12aJ4gXpjbETJb2d9Js9k/WR7UPmWwuYqLRqRHOPl0HXNP1CprVeHI59dqSWrKrxq/1z80cgN3m/7kb9Ppzq1bN4QMX5GTCu7P4wSEu/KmZADRCdirL6YCsEn9HKHiVLN1yAsaMhmLVdjsjakxHVa9UPfHtM2s/EFtWf3sTqe2dn72PPqJAslDoh6gZb/70Bo3P2fFt5vn6EX5sCj/dhim5AV7AASL35Omzzu8FVH3@@JnttNcylPSZ11ZRTGNmr569PP/m4LXrD3cO9@lB13igQrVIiVym@OEtXSSOmRjn5Kgbx1cHVMWXD5zvkda@6Urf4goRGcIRVCf9CKvEbygC2h8eiwdd9zqEnHZElPiLJ6hoaVsjB6mXePalK3/gIPf85VcvXve6awS6MP0fwA2U5R34yqvCel2LHx1Y6rBx3fRRAf83LFjo69@NgDntsOAX3zx@0l5w1wVHrTEOvthlkMffnj/egFUNWX@IKdiFsx/86Z8Q4TCpfxzGxe@N8oNPu5TJVollRH6sEYnKB08aiCJcF2IfPZQ/P34xRqflv0/6BVvd5ZDfPHsJbxqqxL3vdKuWWO/SCGM9sFr2@iHKgor@gCoZT1QsqZpxo4qRO9Ae1rk76d/vEjFm5a8Uj7E@6USvK3A6enoup879L9EOKwR6vYv@fPDgNzJXp5SatdcdhbFzxXLHXXLbrtHr@zKN/rt0HC6J6hzlwahvoujXjPGG@DJv@Qc@Kpw9uRubbbW37KY5lbn3/dzks7H6PCN4XjGA4a/KBP7OOyzt6S4M1mahVKm34Zy/ogOKj77X2Fxo1canF3dqcMX3/tIdvVqd2D54HWD1x9p71zL2/JgudeJPS@m/N1aZ@tX4bm9b7s@z53/p5pyPPvL4yWrZ8wA2MlK0E@u3vrpiJ7ygz9jUQw9mTfvR66AZIWBi3LnAevO@c/OjQEAoKoEI7hQQQS8Ml3U8RTDdAGx8U//GEzxZt57E7UbNL6b9jogxytfzgbGh0EzTuuR0ixhZBq97LebDZb6WHv58Nzmq82ZXhyFDbtWG3FX2yO60sdTpuLVRsF1Gb70XhdSK91oHbuoldR@4TOI39UaMGmMR5rMrUwX@pRMp1rTPyyKcyUORYd0pZThHP2XRCP/EG0m@xItEHhrtZADLm6QMRmhEb/f058BkFi50tr8a@9WD14A5aoD5BzwInOQy6E8LTFI5VcNT/jjb1wDmfJ1FgYE3FP1VOf0CW/82lCJf6yIT3Jcv8oiuTJn0h53lH/1qk6Y/GBLiID6wZ4EpsXu4uTc0@5Gyo/0Bdb@ldQjRMZOfb/H/A76Wxldo8YUur3BKInSBQ0C9/kn3b3DJd9u/oR7/BPs3tH/yf2kTJ9KlZih38Dd99xLcaV2mjcFl5Y18OIX3vw) (online or local)

These are quickly hacked versions that barely work. Only those code paths that are actually triggered by the polyglot were ported to node. 
These interpreters are only suitable for testing this polyglot. I don't want to add them to the list because multiple huge links are hard to maintain.
Emotinomicon does not work on tio because it requires math.js which does not fit in link (tio's node.js does not have math.js).

Comment: NIce Wierd refactor, I never thought of making something with a lot of interleaving,

Comment: back to small number of intersections

Comment: TIO has weird now.

Comment: Tio's Wierd is incompatible with js interpreter: different x,y order for putget operation, multithreading, different gap jumping distance and algo.

Answer (score 5):

## 147. [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 6278 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\D v'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(  >77*,68*,@'1   #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz( coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@      h#115 o# do  xxxxx-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOxx4O6O@ 0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{}))) \';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6 27""ing-?"ye
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main(  ){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001976

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4@RDzD/Kltux7JFkPinrLtry3nrZsWZL19PP4UBQpUaJImaSe@/gigxmkk3RjpiedDm4n3bn3pnswAaY/BD0zQDcSYIDpr438iPM1GMz9B3fWKlIvW/be5ya0RRarVq1atWrVqlXFxWKbN3q//e0eHqSiKfOuopnEFA2TdHR5Iup@kp6TT7xsRIIhhkGolN4dD0XVNA6ZPcIRIquC3IF7YmoDUZUXog7xQUJGutbV@SExe7xJREPgR6JBtLE5GptEk3ZnCxGSG2p92Yc5h7LaBTBT1Ee6aNL0MCENVeGH7Q7/IiXyosCRDukGyYrKD8MfTCJowyGvdgyAjBKSLadzxdQLDDFCLjXdEBGPIBqGhpFxQmY5UXgBmgBQXpe1Yqp0@iKJC5BTIJ0fKeKM8G3D1HnBlDUVkzhSKzVqla0clKUVXeuMBayu2RMhGVkkyYpoMAJU5YSM7IbxY4DsEV3kOxYYI2k6wSxkOFCITITRiLQVvucXiCIDbD4QJyJylCwgXekZZDYaAgZDG4qbdBhEFcUOMUaiIEuyQEsn4swUVQOIN/xEFgZkKisK6YgKZFiTJHgBGRkbG1EWAX6mozEEDmH0ogKru30RYFRxyQRxBExFJmjYBsCRJS@mOj8aAZHAxBoQbspDECXZdBpE5A0ZhRWyGKLaofwbrcRYI7y6WUsykXnCA71jneI2RB3bxk/xkp6oi4CSXwmSa6rLJrAA2ZsiFZHXSV0XRfe2SG8VCYVpWIKJFfHT5js@dubKeSc0o5XDz49MZk8P1a/OGZ74k2T/8Qh@SYfjiMmVsuTz/j2GLQmGph7pLt5Nkj8nBnt/L8JvxrXZrv7MAFYGuKIQVhuZLO8bAYE@EwhkeQxiyDcJ@kfKRsHk@EVbbAiXBdWB1iAFlTS9tGbCWNexl66Zyg@g0oqmdoGfUFl9rCI/VBINQBMIGnQyLxEnwDVNtdpIm1IO13syNJqBTbLRLyxdQxkK2gZkz@boslxDU8YUDnIaJgogcAWyIsaCRJpE4mUFs0A6orKo1kVjrJiYZ6x2sOVBl4gdP1mSIWgdBBpqEyiOB6Q0AvrScKMHUqIAGBpCo1XFpB//5V90ul3AkxIETe/Y4tokHU2gWpGnxIKqISiwmsorlCyA82LpVnYoYMIrcoc3sXh1bhdBiaClTrWx0iEaFKhPZehaPX4C3VGSRMEULSG3FKmXDPmBpTdkS3Kh4kO@DQ1LC6Bl02r7yKcMtJIgMntUZnzDsSnFiW@UI06D/c718dD18cO9CMS5/e6DfZbtHoHA@Q9oFNw535OcZmpL0Rkmb2hyhxnNzZ6mBolPIA4hqY1E1eXcwuH0OvW20@1HfeZyH8lJwS/JasflBBlPQ7lO95GQFO7kw4ejF7k3SwQsU8SCvVV0CW4HAxqH9okJO@Rl1T@ak6bPDm2kacYjchyT/RvRyJeXcRMrYo@OIyiWGsoHqCG/oYjiyBXwc27UEgi3s9qYsKuiL3DYFT6UHzzOPadns@oUA9R0q6LYV@uyhlpLGfXGoKOBKaoxAu2to@gKPAiPgUrchMHcS9pUrKnmB8VCVeJUdOoiaYMeXYoR7ZFWj8P8PtSTNoZ1D1rCbXdosbPRn0EXQJc2jVdKWdGmUDClDYcv0CAqFs53oYkgs1WhlFUhq0Qas121gQp6BbG1RRL3tWXoC9jrQLXbor9RRwAPBS0YwGb1lQ0VNOTngEWwhsR1vyGyBF1qCFpCnxNBRNUDOki0xhUsZEy7oQFmDBo0AV8wEtnuaq96mqmzKd8t6OoF@26Hwspv9inUN0QSp0Th1e6Y76IlpUIWXhDEkWnrK6iJYYJGejns0EifPYb6jR6z/@ll2XQssUfXjTJQ11utZ4@IPCoZ25byKaBTCW9bg6Qj66CdlPnL0gFg8qJwx/cIskXA9443SFgaAiBk4kwUxiYoNxDkaU8WeiC7SJ1qqUdrLHpZPERtlg4K3ietikZiuJNvg4yfXUUhGW@i8GGLvsYDYyyiOtmKoI2/GfE@Zt4Y7kCsrUiE8WAj1s/yfpC9L@Acaqq2AykwcoUWQbZTrHYAg6yGxiCMX0vri3bWlYW4aiJoM9Ae0PNB/nqmOTIOYbiQzd647QdJYev6vGCWVRQW1tTnsqlZ4baitUE9G9A/2WUJrDBuy7MXFaJxqzbsG8wE7DDJIEkYwJ/GIHUup2SA4qTxGQTeSHJQBU5RWGcHAFIgPzDKJRlUJedBqdTmquBy@GlX8kOnc3iJAzuuww0BzLXiS0YbohYiLWofoMGX1kFzSaCtbN1PVT@/c8RbjQHUvHM6/X1NVl2fnR8@fHAeOk9Aw3/48BFCxxj6iCEPhD7SkI@GEM6PIZrDS0OYekdzYNyD8/luiXnmfsBmm@HotJBHLv7u8DD04OXvOPsaxKsbVB1oNoD24QXwON3JJAbdbsfJFCrqb0tW7asWZztUGqqi2mXE2UjTTVIqZ3OPlVT9LOlgx4bOKnKbVWF8fRxCD4a5jGNHfpiULLNDsKppZpI2GMZT6DwA2XM4xtTG0Odh/iEPZbNAZz@KioK9brRlagbKXSOoyKLJ2KPRWtZxIrRuG6gHhS9szokkXRuuNJzBiEJPI479kANt@a1pKg77dmoYU8f2JHUjPobxQ5xg@gWmKwjEp1m3q0gbMI6AOOn0w2SO6Xo8CEknoatIGzJBUeJE1K@3l5GfucAzxq9moRvjyCbGXelvZ1oh5yhyQx0bI6wc5dmO6bQNH0XgjtYWlVk07BMVyW/OFn5UF9EwY12Ir/MWxI68zGyxKwNjQt/3zaQXCbzOWBTWYQwrwpSFFGWDrj5sNjOz6iD3jMPqwKHt0cmxTgmuTcnd9q9jEwsVZhCQgYbqch16BGMvsoUCpu@vc0qy0aOnLdBXFL1OobmNYVuipx0Ah7ZNBV0CJ/jIknOcHqJZp2lEFacUjI4OFBmwSlZ5tkovOE7somd7xNsipi1KY5gysm1ZxfAXwHyJOIWU2m35LVDgC5K@vO4A08ftXWwD4eq9MorIFuPNsW4qYse@/rff70ADvG6eHj@HqY4wWAUegW/YVD7pzdays@INPe1uWQrTHysyT9lAQ19CKfA4HeWVVWA3alTJxOfr8To07nzZuCCceILh9R05syjXRWXcEZfX3YVQFm@bXlZuVR7SGsEV7Ug6jr6R/YXhaOXH6byuaHyHYrGWWWRx3dpWu4gzvguVYzc0EmjIr6Bzad@R9boKGDLm2DrjUsqX2lUe4W83Vw63hSwQ4ducCNNQvi2/wUckI/qWZFsdBk0Pn6TwAyv4iMHdlbWqo8vdLphc9vUtMLCvYQo04gWRndLLO2KxHAwIHej593DqinV@C2S5KLwKvAUIVVXo6acIHxUHAXoIyg4uaPo22CS/YKzCt@doovV@uhRhgXSUBSWTFDyeQAgH3NUMeL10Ohq9nR8tBJo/kdid21plpQgETZJE8Us9F0YfecgrvmBnI/imIl6atOvQDtA@P@HB2FV4A4TEtNksTqBZ6Ok9wcUBRUBxWYfeEds1OcuFjrfmyus8I1nQFNkY0eZe3rylEV/OMtZocB2dntZZ8e41fztg2ONg7VuFdndqTTBxvvqGHH2FkrKmijgZ3xAMv/YW7wRtir83zYSeNhGt8@6Ba7GTqq9QQT6FSgZMFl9n7whfEldc@KSn3Vwc7KTKFJSd8YfkUtP0nqgaJOgPoJmj0tV6GLYVxZq71gvlt2XakBXNIDV6fo8XMCEwDOu8W5o32Sbzqk/oWX1sFd6dbSdRdJAjKXp@o3F5pasp0XiX5eH0pgSMdQk1vX39Wg230lAc90UNtTJ6NJWzr2@q9gH8f0k46DqsjssTG8F3bKld6sye1r5dQZgX4Jrj7srlA3Ga089as7i3GkAXelN@vrz@DqPHW9xdjh6jOTWZwabDDIk4BEzdMqN/l9LC75fW@Tod9Qpt7EuV2GjcgSKCxqbnV01KggHuJ@bgAoGv11iSMhbH4k4NUm73RRCb93TH1xMVsKuxb697sMA8fES7glrYE8KvohrHc7x7V@Hwigyd/IvWzE5VMwI7e4QT6AoEKhh4nbGrjkdbjbvBu@pYrb7Pud5o2bO1zhaRmPJTNVL8yzbTliluiPT3ltmeG2ow7dWGYEOoX9H@NlK6RGSdtxDTmDXmvoyrVfq7eA/Jah0T7FewR6BV5YHhwyWvr1M8wbfm6xQ4kYAZmSqaczy/xe1dirStacpPaR3Qpx0ZzTQwPtFX4Uut9Mr2sZe0yXplwsBVjrb01pqENdbYk0fgHk6U32zoClTJpIPD17TyqzXAd0atjRXBL80hYcSmCz@GLizDb9Fbxc7N@eP@2LsEL1fF2GXgPWQJf@hr7KPR0uilC664SGsty66dLfZe6J/RHDgld3yG0BOHIr19x@LnO/2xsby8CTTT8Lcj2c/SJdM38o1k6PAqnreWgDdMIlNTRYM1eb0r4lxFEXmwRq3Yt5TsciV2J3MLQ74r5r8oWetlB3zYKejyVnD3AsSh9fxBgGxfUCPWNFBTB@LcWF53G8tzAdpzPHwX265OLuDq5hd7tZ/dufr8BZtP7Wk9tSf2dNozVndv9Q2QSNNyw3qvEkB/jzcG@HSXKqT1HK9nbHJX0RTla7iLCtFSj5q2e@E1h15VHcj6k/DO@TYk2JcvrtHBuE2ZRAfwt/pOTxzD8GRopjYSffTuLVAFV3is8@615ELZaZCWLOodrAnK4hCKltuKSKYykNA3Np8O7F49aisajw4E71jwwJnl9WvWowRN323JnfKaCcbp@yNuntLzpXE5LZv4sL/7BcCt5mmLvKnKA9bu3/btbjne1ra0ajLxZTHar8jADH3ux1ZObqbX8FLY3bPlou0@@W61MmNdn39ZKs3e2FrSx8Dr8uwnftRDbOVEYHht1zaIk3XbkclYeQvuFVRBF6lLwfIRM9lDR4fxcKzwpqb7CYVzuXiPx@1mrEy4zNBVAWwJRf210InDcgUziCIbJoWVJXJ3R/Y/zw4Dh9wzSRLHoYM8PFhYqTtBbjaijlZVK@vdPv@Q3Hf6fM595716SAJOCioqMOvbCcpvwUkyvVh0rqtOVH5I/UYwvKzpkeWcYvSo/xfIVQckvQFmC12i0nTLxcLy46njs4n/@tcd2y0OximDDGUDrPyuiq6c2lDsadOPVrl26anRiEe3OsQx7eHiO5buy6SIAf0UxmXqDadNSSNfj9vONbazKdxUcHTaoMJqVLSY0OXLtBrNoqajiZbs2AWvci0rJWjKeKiCduiYPcNPaqAzROq8s3rcCiEEU00dVWTHSwqkI@KqcAcJo1aBomkD@hwZKfmvf225FEGijCKE4WXx1KNwo0SClg714xEEbQxUL5EsRF2zQVzIZBiZxmhwg@SLVrybCD2e@jqBJPqWnj5YjOXtk0nViC9HnOgRi/4DR7Lk2k9VT5t3gYfkz8mQFf/b77PuzzbfHD/zxaKGw0uWIEfPKFebyRFIXqc6iWN/5rCrhb6X1NVwJVS2f7ULw7S5lp47Q@q2SeVOnFLPHfpAXMWBF/0hVQP6B9y6KWqr0yT3XWPLuvPVTBJBt2EwmHgIWY6e1AMOvVAwy/6M/EB6KCs@gXCRANxZDFHQ8WmYTC@f7IU2H76yWbE9pg8iJkF/MJSk1dl/TB6f0JAudjT0Q7z77n4WDPjuZ7HcA2ssmXN/P/tZIHgN3NNg4Nn/lsUOlCtlP@/7TwI//GDwc@JwPDuPrIfR0Mv3P1cKlVytnqo3asDNZ6uye3lNH/JrTYGyMFJ4AbqPQh08gS26LBpf1h4rDbK6A3CXi@zz5Bg9w93uVcIK1Ga1w@fYt4IrELDANnN/Ifuu/Ia4kf4awNZMkkxsLUoqVJBsmXEamxrUu5QtbBfs7mPQ2UuOoGvADlVIeeQgSeCSD7j0lTwir2tpteBHGgHN@GVGvY9jFwrg1RriNQAyaVUW1tdKtyq3s/LP/wQ1HsG49o@tMcXxbo0R4r0aA@A6G82RTxWKjWpuOxOI09qbH6xcHd/RkGjfsvyCLenSbB/UpWaiBqJh@5qtdKtBJrJBDUiUNwlHBpiD0e5In0caqF0IKjI/SSkGaPJOB1RTe26iZgOV7qc@KJYjik8ljj1gln810HqJg0FYI/naFxE011QALfa9lXmfwlHMBrPDd/peZH/8l39h@UvfmxD@IzssQfhfWOHvWGTQa59Pi8YVa5AtzUKFGNRyxYoP@dlGnXDEwhFRVsHakofAwQllCIJbxK7ru8bjumsCP6ERgJmoelHb0vJE/cGFHnuHLIsGBq41@KkfgzgTqE1LHfiexui/DgMEG41EwxyYeqJvskToky2EvpGF0O0@BFljJvIo@X1bIMfHx8RhCLwiJqNHFiPZff67kOP7FaH7AMtYtsgdgTyQZZ0D0k7sbK593sO5MSt2OSfnJA9HYGZY7QIjlYsGAMSN0arNDwcMhZrNKmh0VZyZVJ3PlzYWGDgqdcQSrbcYloh8gMjCjW7WL2V3/Xgc3YY2pNm/2QyOFoLVEOzQsUt07r4j9@a9@mB72xMQmF/tECQVwn@8wwV/JT2p187frpeu21gb8qmmaugykQdqiSvIBkMsF3Vv9BSHjQroxX7xA6CEngA9SxDlvjYyUplc4bxcqb1yXqaQzpdgTuI8Ofbc@/zeu4dVwPlC6pdMTefZ2mU6v2TlJlXrVUeEWC89viRzV2kvKX2j9Jbll/C6bJrwqiAu8LWI6TTfl6er86@xr1PZDcCM9dz0Vaku9@fnu4fjk3t171XxP@x6r2PPf4DCBaF7g77V4SQ7dE5h6W1Rx3fxDP/SfS/oWL@1tHJatO7X0W@7H6/e7Fv7IC/9OtD/OHjCdsQJq44VhfG/4fEBdfezVlHUAdcibEkv6JolqRySui5QYF6tHG9SQ@y6vH4J0fbDXDGpbE1P6fsVvAozE10WLGiDKmhrEktfBoBpTMFcz3xgNoWrfXSCN6eTGVAVq6fQHZmuecH03a7BKqUmDmVffUkPKo61TzEoMvSV7UHdYPJ/xCfvZmTlvfieu7HfGCmy6UI/35kfJ4lQG5cbK8AdKyK6CR8nHmyfZLJ0HfZQ7@PKGPhV0UZkPTHPistQFeZmJDsG5CAGIjkfDwFOopeqiKOESEqaDzIDH51LIu6gFJddB/@wE4HS/T1x1pG7MNK43F5QST/juLXfMu/2wITaCXrYYtUpPl7fZMxP8rXe4Bh/x/tltSPOXPhezeEDcgfindPWxOl2vJIB6vBte393Xnp@L5UFb9q9du01/UIhJBIrRbDddxIJf89g0LsU5hVQYs3UixCEMdQlDfkRcY2p67xB/ITeuu5dqtcwdTfxneB4NiUq8XjojAQuNMFPaE6JhmQF17Nc@MKZi01CO2OsoXbwspBH5I7z@x8gTAtxk31cU8iAuYGzcTcDBidkOaRoYQCGv0OkaApzL6TIuu7TYhlcENABamcy7cjdHu2AwAtaa3LyLVlrg3UPtLiaSBzarbGtDhMExOJ4h8YAtDvU3NLiBP7aLoLANVRiAJWBqaYMCuXThaiq0F9dIDND6J2EH4OQ6W7v8iVo7/pFOlrCnkXime1zCIRuv2CXc35WNLBn9tkjOq89eoZx//t7HPgle@ifs7/H@tmjz659JTlnwRhzn7j2e0nOEzrwePbVA9e@iubIt9/idPh5H6ydR7/D75gBkG9fcR@BPIN1lNxXj/b5Y9d@Jxk8oDng1uNxf4YMPzdY/@d9/pnd/xasCS/E6FbvdO0bbuwOAb@fewb6sIfss16Qmc8uB3HQV5ix@H3Z40Ea/PuPSMDP2fuah44r9zWWzryPbCOX7Q6XamTbVlm1xKtXsi0G2tGHK40eob7j1mOlxyXw5vt1O9J22Ue//e0eF4VJ1MdoyKV9DIY@HOyRvU8O9sChOz7fZ8nEecdLQf/TQ2VQqVy7710gks69TNnBhR3fEXLAMnvsQeCHGMt@//33YH2SuxP/if/BfedzPty5CDmJxQ680fiB95OTo5NomJBxnNsVDLpZcl8j9zGeP/CEg5/Uoxwef/9//v0v/v5P6d8v6O9viSzLI6PTgZ/WIwOygGMgEfyn4UVnI8xjuC0tXPi6KJhySRSzb@DgKk5nJOSsfYdvi3z8AH/0H47VLZ4/0Bg7moK8Pj64ietpxuydCHuLPY7j9ub07xHDHDfbdTxuhFmOC96r3@D7/NEPn74BlokeehwefqLzIEcs7tC0T9aMsgdYI0TbQ2Oe0Pw@PJi9WZ3HP1Jv41/VxL/mAP@qAv6lB/hXXODfLpKYvZ8nk56fevj9j8sQs/f98ffJf8RB6wd0wJxm7@Tk4fnZ47vzf3fkOTrCH/6DPlgGj@hhhYCIB4/Pc3x3fOw/OZmd@B5O7pi9z8CTZ2Yv6ADhvT9g9pKz4yql9C57YtP8ZE/TixA@9j3cVYpgite9wWPfXjCfyniDtUZ6j4O7yPoWE0N4W82lsuUGQFeKuVQtd1po5hoViDceHk8@ffL4oVU@AXdOHoCW2c88J56kaZrk9vHAT949HneErFtmL3sya7C@YyC3aMdUaUG@e7i7d/tPHn5g9u727lwfgx@DASUwCXADbnCpldf/5fJsFi5Hy58IpMuzQF/TA71Aj@uArJKA2AjMA/NZYKiVuQ4ERfgLDCEoB6RZoBtQAyrHbeF7@39Y1i7LGqDSIJs5C5iINSDBtVsuXwIyCQruw58cCARmQOgsMIH/gEL7DffdYwDr6A7c3zN3xPG9CArFzzn9Aac/6nTKD5Ho6OnzczD6dEfNjUji4U6cyeaDg3idj/d3iUTC@XC0xxr396ylYx3BsOMIQZ6fHx@zqXrq8ZHF1ZfZ8b7nk8f3CY7kiefYvnzc65wcfbw/9KGEW1Luf9xjjz/en4R8GI56gO9BiDtmf3KvWaGE64d7xumatlot/LWmk6kVogEr7r61SsVTi4UoK4RRcCAouyv/dmD2WthcrrvIw@dnN0zf751HTotRLhcRwUZ3Obj7WVAiQYebGu8JGPm4ENpX0Yj75CQagfto3O1zBWiyleXeMRqN7h1@uhjgp35RyWRK1/k5BQrD4Hvv4PXHe8dd8CGZTERodMSXiBJN9yVCbofb/R13fGyXEXRDtMM5c2i6k3x@3vxzfX4@dtHDjX9uN0ba5xO3C5LdEbibfXbNjl3HLoyDKMz1@fkEgxTuM4TuXO4H9/OzFQdnl/vYwnniBr7hisc/4b9mEGNEnHvPe2g0qSQccbvac9EdjrrinoT9l/wAFXA5Qs4Q1Mvh5J13d58OQgex8N3Hh4OHA9fxgf/g/uRhS4G7nXsEuspStJPcHvKN2fMfVR1c0OFEUT/CRxeaIvoVrUtCiaNtYXA@ug5eHnEu4TnwfLo7SCSssg8OfvgAvRLQQWEOOPZAfomLHJ8cr4RqhXHmPgHYz8RmMoSfP4OcWYlgg7nshxP397OA1dvJUTu5/3mPfz6i@Mmzw3m0Ja8Uv8t5RJ9eOT479nn9jntwPDv2P7ef0Vg94NzUJoqEj44OwlY4Focwd@C2FmQjAbhbhiFFNHiBKoajPRQnJ/DcDbVKtsWurIKBusUkTyQSYYNwnv0smgvOmCN8ymM9UnL4HFYHIvEExbdHDCPBwHyoDS0/JbEAjNoKvvOhSdIHKx4mdqQtimBbi4qCy5M47wHzX@lMYa79gdkDPQYmliHCMazw4lgUp@PxVFwdGdk45PvE1Yd5Ox4//uoPfvzV//jjr//kx1//wY@//sVvfvmLP4DfX8PvT6zrn/zHRATPv/nl//K//viXv4bIv4Xff4Hff/7NL//N71s/ev938Pu/N@L@zv5twFk/BnD989/88k//6je//Bd/Dr9/Z//@/OXvxz/7T9b//2P/YfDXP/7Z3@HJvvmDP2H@4W9@hf9/@jf/8F9@hf//27//h7/51//wz/8DDfyFFfh//91/tM5Q@C/@@Md/84dQpz/D8D@DMPwTj886PDbAH2HkD/sBMDfJ/Q@bkD@wHIxAhN2I/CPywz16nXJrSMD/b39gAzBIBizIFc5NyD/@zS//1V9B7A8wvnKcDfmHy@y2DG1BruhEM84q648A@C83YP7ox1/9/o9/9T/8@Ku/@PFX/5wBuxn@P5APTJDgFU8YSQM0NDtgIiEQ1WWYW4dDYRqOwHmX8YGPcz5@2oqycB/sAqaAH2n6h522DJZxsKRtV2Eflvl3YvhIPkEyDFt05JrhGW8gBsNU69HLMmpmA9J7C8a@38hpxVj3ZCP7djxGbmRcXnZFWwm0yCUQsZHN7ELJGr1dDWZJmQU8exXBELt6DBMjjQqcqoXTs/rGtZ5LZc6YKEmXS9kXl4gNFCHFXL6@uo1ZqcuskRWKm1yx@PLWvtxoh4fJn3PhGANXuBsTgUdtRTeZmNFtoPzHxyDqDHPy2Xd8zJzUcnVIqJcJFwz4mZNrMvOTSuXK98yc4GpN0lKRXDj62WcYDIP68wOJxLxev98PJ7x66UGv/v3vliDc25bzngOmkRGHI0qCMYcD9Kjvo2MuMpf4pCLBWY4jMqKBkC4m8FE56OKpSj0V2rg3yXj0diRcMAqDutztmcScaisAwzDABFsZZ0vDbGWgtUib5/H3Uw8oQdw8zPcjTKsMGvcqRXkNzpzBkDTETQLQCc3EmbsskQDjx9YJBhPxSDwRCsa98UQ8HOGikYiXC3q5WDyWCHiB2XEuGo8kOG88nAiFw@GEF5o7kogxe6LakSWWhRkXB1MvvMqqgC@/HuNbxJq/d8LsdUQJnSrIzNVxk73OKmIcJ45Q/D5AIKODizL4gPNglgTLHR/9hjjCORgHTwSyl89nAvm8w5HGG9DegUzA4ejgTSQeCMTSDodIUzLxUCAImXp4l4sG8E0Ch4w3mVQ@jxj6eBOMIw6HY2ClWDfK8iYGYCrehEKIgDgcTyt0AUCuWRTFaS7TugkE0hmHY2yRF4c/gEtZd2FKbA5vMAEz5a2UDKQ5HKfLTDAoORxVC84u6mxZ31TK4ShYN6kUojinlY9YlbrAmxQ9IJMOdyC8DkcXAl0dzA2How1BFGGHQ4CQMOchbggh9LxVTd7hmFv1wJo4HDMKzQsDh@NxGQ/lAD1nZ3zP7Ihd65jr1lWApAIkybNxLt8@PW13u219nsqdVmnS@fkZ35@P9Xa3bWdsP8KhYS5IGgznLw8Rkx4feWV30gUkqS@SHuePIqXwkX8CyuyjiwUNH88x6RySdq2F2AjhGAJwG4/0EK5pvm0lLQ@aRK@zdttxBELLYO8hc5f7M52VuoghL0RQOq6AdwxzpcjHcdwRjTkOD@Dq@OgIQXDmIgEnWL8O573D4b5LPHx0xCKOQ@fHjz7nt9xH4oglHIeOWMxB3Ee6aI51lQSPnrGcRTJwhNcnF555L57baEV/tuHaR8@ocl0Y9eRaeJKclyzcH5E0mN3BfNh9SIk9embZY9QA2GXhSpaqmi6rA2Tc4QP9TVYAlqpY9XXi84HyJvADGwbTR0mr3i5HwkXQgiVwvndQA99a8HQ5nbGg0@l2HgGSD8SxoczdRxbRFg9dS0agigdGJGA@avPBlfDBbIn4ElCBVyTpg0PD5HVcAaclHhJHNOHAaNz6MLEs7JPXx3kPD9qR45P/jrGGpijH7D0zHXz/NZwgR4kjXEyCaeXxiZ3ngsznvMe3RPEtIV3PPrPvRLKdoa1pdiqZ6lZTyylMKsPs@UJaWNvb399n9o7rJ46Qo@x/XC0hnLB0KeoeV6hwYcd//3j8wfM7rS/4/CeflotpQDjL6CI6Z3Vwu0Rrmh@PICO7xNjz/I4HFMIkASdzhBNBx94IOo@gkDkuWZJ7q0LHP9@jywCk8nnpKzNW6eO8w0t8eOPiD2t0Z4K7B@L@eUlWPsdDvhO6@o2CSaBln2uJ72Lfxb@7bJQb5fynwGH8MH5/bzefl3NyTto0j59gCJKrOWbP@MGtRbifq@dHe4cjZyjsBGv4PrlnVZuLufdOgjG/wc/3HmwfU1c4hrIJ93RWGOTIntTaPqZbN5MhXUSEouK/1@l25eDvXX7/wz7LOp1gne@ffP6K4/nu@Pj5GI9nO4Cn5@fn41f/9LI@3oBZp/9uEuN/3HuI/tx3bP0fwylTtrjjiEYcbnQbNr57/O5xD/RAgjiCEey0HpZYE8/NabJrdqB@d6DCn3hg0D9RpLfqwfEJRBkQYd@LCCG6D1iWvQqC2ZFIROPRPea3LPveI3dIXT2DkkRRN8bDXQ@hUrp8yeMDOnX1IAoCl@OFqMN1ufPi0kAhaKHgU1Y0UTbjbKtlI4puWLodNzdYdPTDWDBqcWtLuhEukVATunDhxaQOW@QAt4tFf2Y385n5BnCNBZP6CMLpiGG@QWc1vHUt4bzkW8N0oyNPwM18842t2w3Tb5iPiBwz2ZE@7oh5ZpA9fKdjEHw@SP1yLCdoHl2/tJH1RpkyJ1Ymg45Rlq1F/Zex3A2CD4hkUQG1OSC0REo5Vs4q/hsLrD2WkJR8oZiDPCRJJPqc2c7t0Nu4MRit3gfJbRdOAhCFWBCccoqCIyCgg0gXxe0eoqe14KKQHsJhukSfVwMUmJ5eSomXSHbGO7x9gOyIXhIUzQDEVukuqwbk4NEu1q7DcsjESgALsXZ0GKJDq94VvHbr4U4rdw9u8nnpz@nCVHJMgmuHUxsXNIa1py/NKAw7luDQHddsNlNs3IMXmvbI8gt0reDsmDWjnpkD0zs8sppqdMRcuAT3Z3yeefTz4bffCt@N7oYPR@5h0sSrxzOEUXHgki2QAzM5TIJ4jO7khyPzzuORH5JD94UL72HABUvimZEsZhtuu25QczUJtKDPg@H2Lu5U38/VB2/@TvUAyWPvwW1y4eWTAe8MfjIYF4r3KcnZ9YAyzeTCox7xx/DDR6tbPpdgIXj4o60ozDJwKcnFHf@QBH4okNHjyUNlgE7jTvF4HtxQuAKJrzMeKd9@y3uUk9mR4vO5Eeq70Mf8nQmBB08S7w9d/PHs4@JuDPkPXXBNQjGKG4iHfDavn1e0A31HwGOrTdekWzTOkLwZkDdMJg9uPx7cHiQ/fFjczXzDB6/F/sPAWhqQ@BkSf7Th0@o6uHWTFyyhi6Eux8/kw5/5Dwzi8MoeDzDZO9rIaVF4cAspI49nSfUz6ku61ejysT1KmO2Hae3MRvdwoqvtdEdUg@4CbXbQIx3ypgxBlm1w61WCkQzTXR73LvUSVVN9PIXANHvrY0y8n338yCyLtp0EoWRULm2R8Dhtpjtf6rgyS7fRtl7j@ZJ@3aWGlzp3NVusFW5zBCamoehGd6WqiXY4QxfuEATVwOfA85GlsSzXUFA2VHsADNUeCOdDLYJMsvWEDZm0E6G1lg0EuVBPSNZrTLgFmIH6CdTbuueDCrHIgM68gwzZ209S3QTyJEOIyMe0PAhAV2G@gUogDVgH@YGcgCIj335L7NvjJEy2YzgWIBjC9T0cAr2iFAr/CkoBB1LZBxlFfUgLAdq@wRR0aN4qKPyPK8h@H8EFGTx9r/Vagp@@luAaq4b1Ng7yzW2RgW3xzTd9TzJsEwT/dFYA@SHt@bd79nB/SDLly0qjnqtepmpwhtlNfL278uFqH95Xu2@OcFfNtqxS912Br3LizbkAJgzYrCZu0oS7bHfIeaNIgsFS1otbKgDr96wlMBhQD1eYRINuV2f4Nb3LTuWBzG5vz487IlNPYfoxAN9ye2Qkhw7OyvodofUrQgYuWcFgbr8HvrVB@1A0DHtTUd9yn3a6Fz19W2qIL/1AL7Q3IaVOWEs/Euq1hA8lvNQXTpe7Mt18u2ch2MpP94s0rey0fzC4eWiHN3mUaCYRDwQOScCLAW4ZCC4DoWUgvAxEloHoMhBbBuLLQMIOcEvMnIUZJqKhUHQdjK2D8XUwsQqGA@vgGkM4uA6G1sHwOhhZB9elhVelReMUL9lbcpN2XVHHNC4cX6bhi4CqSSMjgIZ7GRkGQoOvICF7@FUklBffjowlAnZBBbaMQMFgdH0P2mcJm3RZVHktOrxWydadHQljFWPN0ajA5nQdtFJuhrslg9C5Dwm@88AwoHaJoIg8GAOiCVZKMg/yL7oPrXcB9fnh@r0HxJDkVveQHXcThTwc3fjbEp8dycFdyRa24E5s1huXZMWYjZdGbCItKg@3RloLY3grbhPrB1SwyNE3IIIWBLbB9lsmyzLr@nhnkaH3i9xCuLPIV0RZeCO7ciFvXBR5cpmVjv8UW3JZnmWniLS1wQywv/JAZeBFg@JLocnP3KHjN7/88/@d/OaXf/pr8uNf/vr/@8//M4b/E57@D7BZSHAF8Cd/iqd/i6d/jae/xNOfbWSi8KFDx49//iu4/Z/@A/nxD/7USvpXf@XwhleIIAWj1jl/8c/w9Id4@r8c3sgK8Bd/bAFiFof3mdkyrVwA9Sd/SwiUhlhWyP78rwlxeMDAcNmSd2f18YeNV8gsBCs23NHQw8t06yz0dGR7wO1xAF77jlvfebAB3BvIdR4/W7Due2DOWK7LqKUFXujha0J2lGag/SOgCaMZ/i7I27QDRo@9tuGE2v/35JA4PQgD0fRd2KSlw@362/V2rFMR1uNggTrcCdhGhWH3ihKY3jIg33QmMDf8OG2hM1LOkhGbvyX8LMpyAHEsJUs2XZybscta5oZJD7F3l4f/9VQXhRaHIetdUvqVB8Z@44XbKHBL3bxoNijlZQxMGddvl21mpRHicARNAtlW/EbG4g3lgvclunXL2d0mV86/6DB4tMHEHGxqpFVBSeJwfAEWOW3Du9HiCm3DW/TaAHeBw9DD1rtqu4Ad19fXDmYjLoAypHdcFMNGpSyVsUritpOCG0nBjSSg2cJJdU0kGHxBAx04UC9uv5dpZdtQUdvZ1sKFPWfZDkgGzAWt1UyvpIyNXvI1aqqRt5Xda@QbKLmHpN1P7lWqc06Iw/0qA@DczpN82Za7UQdewbxuqN05kdtbMVut9TamrTwbnYJyj3nJpVXLcYldLbdd4DuouQfPVxYUDPwjC/J9ZUHRyJcLetmsmHcL/dv8/bLaWaqJlYZfI7M6/t7WAIVD45@D6K3VEVKs06DLDVOelD3laU814trxGQGIZ5d7KG19O0Df2FkJJzElzRSt5YFPIw2mHBpawRvfHtr1/TD7Uz9dVdNFY/MdVNl6n0d14lvQgtZVYVTz4l5Osv1hDHyIbm2KsT2urEY22wrNWJ8zQtQWo9DyfHyUVdl8fATjU5HcawbirV/AlyycDH4HCUIb@V0r07Y8cmm4J53p/jJOau9a2eqyMHCVR3aiEwpJEZjQCaICky/S44UBftGLsgSrSN8IRYu0bbrcyMSeNtS6oqrhC@CY@wX6who3EsSPRpQWL@G9RNigyJ5EuwQv77azXvzkrOQi6OLdq/zBbQRbzPAS/SWPkbP6juIe3yzOyrYsr/bT6a1t0lt7n15J1g3zJc00Eld78PrTig651hgAcE1G6MtkeO09H16Rs0XKKho/z2Fl@GoSO6IhwPCHlKYANGWD@yWQD@/qzoC7FeHNt/j/fgMus@e@tvmoMVubg74Z5tD2o1M0g26LowqiC8ALbtQ9r4tbiXb2K8uyJzp0huclDqq4VHxXBzrmaCSqxuqx8hLxF2QevXteyT11@UlaiTto0ideMgi@3UTZx46o8HOx47IhvRt4lzWuinyH6quvqzgqOqr0NOubLK6Al9syxeg7lRTo8A2R4b0Tt/ttsbJA5JX00IdxlMLC2/yjC3cvVTMugiatZyCaDhp0j26mQrewGc1Hc@s9bMX6FJytR63xx2rJEr6e/kWGAB@sD31x3nWx7vfUZ9W1qtJXjAgrWP92lfFVyyVGfNnxdRv@NBZ9uaZ0lWGVKbls5S3r5K0Wl99r8Q2pWMqkZZV8nUh@Sei@WuY2RM1CtlZhmZ82hLzCnOEVRRBcmxitmHdbTFNf6QSMwxbT1DdGlccdCnWVk2o6E/fUT1r2hZuRIViA6wSuTbgiQpiDPloCtawb2rXLJS@aMuRHG1aLHXMnoC26wUX35nPEDShmGcaF3OdVmcKbZQqvyhS2ylz1gO0iN4AYYatIuxWwed5rAkWUzDe0MybhzB0u76ltOFSN1/HZ62en7DyUvcQ5cR6CQnaKzsOcC5Sys@M8zNKA4Tys0cDAeXgBgXXfcv7gPFx2CwTQ4ZYGPmG8rcLxXnAeZlzuZ4Z@AHRZrt95uGpTgPlo3VKOPFvLq237qb@2WlUVRa9lVHoJSowBFw2rdffgpb8A/FNQe4cySPyQJMEDCowTkK1BY2PEsMqBYcNPvzDo2jV8HC6Xpuz1jfUaCqR7khuLKiglY6qPnHvObWVkEYapdPERrkAg6s3D3RQR7tXM7Evk2KWDhNJG3i6fcs9P7YGOi6bfAfDmIo6yzr9sr20UVgN@HZ2Y@S06X5GzLI5ShM4A7h1kIVO/d75TKWzrF7tdWa2/2UKv1wiwEX1LEKuVKNoNnQ42HNqmtLCRNtoWEpqKT/vkzTx42J0SpfdFNqoV7J75RjKNtmuGimGz87vfq85GPiRtSwVh4l3gweplq3GB6mJMWuu6DUvV6nxAwobO6dCNKkQU26wdpHCWuvHSseKtYWiZ1yqSaq5tNQmZ/fga3Zg3rdLXz2Xw5bqfNn1d5gQTHGhEBBs5V6VY@lX7Cfa7ZtnvS4N6yYQXBewyrHcPpa/N63dH2ReUK@tiXzcgJnpJ1r3TOFqVsGY5zA42LPP3ZO2ViY@fWrKMfKvQFfYX1v6Sbas5wRf49nJuYeFCK0GfbEcOcGF2EHybUa8tEmXiXxotfizJxmNVfEXpumrv02pVfFcTYwqO0XD5yQ2sbzfwZuMhPloB/QXLrV6On6ykzylWfRvX1DeeXFhPHTT0Elvt3bYRCeqe@q@tXLQgovxYzZZLxRsYdGOxmPv1owjstZB3PY4z7z4mWE1bgl7cqId@SBt9J3qabn64Vx2vXcpoBBgDPH1uY4mf3cfdti7b0Ocv@i7ks2A3OGrjGqy7Ab@lldDU4XHIlm2@Wtt8uw54G8nSvAV@e@lsDZ8aoXTgA53HRzp8PT6ic87joz2KYdOsHiP9ds/@0ldw42vYe9veTNTiMl7thoELAOOh9S1mewHO3ufC8kPZw@@em8vcq1xj1ZSXzg64PoSPqFaeEa4Q57Y@l76Msb5qDpLqCoZxChuM4FvJVi6ExoVP6lppl/PBMnRwE1djpKn2Z88HokrNdtxS1lguvVKyx@qUp24gVin0ZeoNiiyHrOVzMfolY7qxuvXZaF61lpCXvPESseunT3yCCZhyDOSRtY/byvXDcNNMlGDqowU8biviEL8mDLK7YzX5UoZW6eXlbhcEibX3rrccXOr4gWGfJvkyy/1J9kiTfhPa3v/S9gmje8/a68DATtfWBjMGCUbBmkp4gbPrHzAW3WQIbiIToE5aFAp@MbjErGDcu5H3g2vu3r5yy8ON@D64HrFlrbcwZR33qZ/w6gaf7ZczN5am7YeWVA9sPLlc7pXE2HtbJelzSj/6qI1cjj3HcgcpDFpuE7wiLLdeceGmP4fMNypVPOgBRgTLtwYMXBWNNvp4zb1ySVXJz0goSD@8CeVRK5UWCzisJ3tb2CENsiKxlnefrWAcP@s4foYPE5lv9lAXWrKG@ZeijGG6E@ZalskHG531QAW7stUFljeRjZsQTDW@2VHwB5fDA1g8DrdjCxPA208/vrE07@usoBTdv2XrnWgrr6VSqfqQ06unqW6ql6rewH06UPS0@uEcy@bOlE4qW2jPT7VYfSIFA/Wbq3Q75KnEOrORfDbMnI1yjBy@GXpuQ7PEWXgRyYQyKSFwLZ0WpXAscy1dG2JKERPspD@46ojVUZvTDfmidFmqLth846rZvepLt61WP6bWmFH1Nt29molX8ZY6aTYSBeNKbGZK5qDUN8fcvBxrRRtT1Ug36@ne@bwwHcwKUe1GjmSuxFhTGp1NhXlkJJw1mNtJvRetnc0HCW7YmacyRucm5vGwN5l0N34mdG6l81rmotPVI@3IoJbgQ5PhuTSa9y7O1KdiP1ObCJ5RP1@IThi1UphMxXBr0FbO1Ntqs9nOpivTAWfcjjr9cOtybLbjejQUGqfEXj8cKYxNPV5Mpy5iZjZVaOaV66Z5O2/GK4x5ZtZjjXMhoXgmZVMIjbMN1gg0Z@fyRW0aPQvWtTP1XCn0K4PT8WlFGY0H2bBcrg/Devc639aCwbOr2uTspsjo4fPWTbzaD8azwkxgLyKaNgzVE6Wifjkbp5/KYisj1NJiOxpIR65zXP@yPBfKk2K12qqMWo1hzLjglNt8oM@Ur4VaKj3IF4dxrl6aF@Knhdo4kynMJu2g1NVS404rdHkdnRZLYqF1xYbO@LF56ZEzZYXtn58b82bjonBdMm6hW1@ey2FpPks307r0lM0Yl9UiW9IHvVq4r3ZGzZic0YTzSiFsFgaps2nrNlFID0Sp0h5og3pLaY1NOdtn88w8M7hqtMVpXl5M@Vy42Lxi@7mqYMZS3VCN7UtSe6CUjUX3tLjo1sbtbidRPg1kxaeLTroZqeZG3GXeCJfUOXNTT0vyonolcYNK4qxw286l5Es1kqmIo8rp2WQWDN7IUmUaWXCz634@LM@EcKBYTl9feq7Og1VP0ZNOV7RQucsEs/nTVjdy4dHy4oItSvxTLOPRx@PwLDvG70cXG6qiDyNKIJ6ve3oxQ28lLi@nbaNwXc20BGURv70cDKK3VeZ6UjA0PRg/z6cSbGUQ0E/5fqlwG5PVfHiaPlVyiUJr0YibueJYiZ8Vu9nzqp6tD4XrRK5bm88H3fi5WCkOUowYz1ar/Xa32Z7d1IzKPHAZFvptT@40V3rqQj9u1vLB80Y62h1XQ82LrDqp1POehXbdKo4ypQGXq8TH0XosNGQms/N4qmaq8ih7epmIXo3lYi6V7TYynCaK10/CBTfga/V5IG7E9Kv89dXI8Jj1thZu99Kh@dXlDdu8NYzImczczlrRQmqgCxedmXluxOpqUCtfBbgrqdRQIpOW/HRT0fqpIXvRuF6w7ekiP6uYglkbaJFOLDI4nRlP@uJCv2DiN31eaZQyWrEvRC9u5EWMjXBq/SYjXQo358FAqtE9uxTzZ5PuoiEOg/2zp/GZwAtGJXXTPlWik9nII4XikyJTL7Wuu7Gnp0BbLN0k5NSgUa0UzGCdZ8c3tWLkqXhjGHmhUZDTYVkdZ9M3p4Nh5nbO143ZYlyPthVpXtGDgRwzK91cNoW@1jXyxq3QX1znb9XLcTB6Xe5LMbMz4IYyV2xKgVhpVPVkPRXltN2dR5tjcSKAZTi6Koy4dKrfLzNlbhibpOcJw1RPjYtSO3OeklOpYjx4NQrGzgaZ07NZR242mqWzDq@Fb9uZULTc7gaCnXQp162Eh91YpRQLFzNMvT2/qnKdbFzmeryS6Z/Pw6NEMZiOss1p9eyqX@@pJSWTas2kdEioa9NYi5fUhriIxtjLgKffS5yrqUC4EmUaZtZsFPPTkEe9KFwGK/O5cN3mxyFeeroxPMLNorcoN0VeU3rFpypXb46LGbnfb0bTQj1QTtcC44Ux5UfFCpPIVlQuW5xN8tNerRUwRtmzUbw9K3UylYrYHnVCI6ldTs2kwKTVur26apTV4fXV8Kwaa5cXHb4faZpSNVqemcwTmDzNSbGRb8@ykiH1q5Mn9XQ2vm6y4cbpsNjoTDz9xO3NJCRflwPFUrop8ePCVTdmNkqz0eW5IinsMFjussy0UVksTDGl5UrTy5uZ1FwsUnLaeOJmFyxfPC1kr01PIpdPZcv1Gq8r5fJpMZvih9PLafE65hEXtctORB483TIVVVWC@m1NiaUDISPYiGQXGaF/Ghifpof183qCG3GNs@bl5QXXU4ShELspZ6OtS6GVSp1fzM8lvlmpjCoXjTpT9qjXt7d1tlxXigmpWKjWtUhhol@2WjF@qqWu@EAhPGxPi7P09HI8bg0T554bU@RD2kIUuepUKbLiGchOnBHHk0qmVDHmwadF/6k7yWrXzURqdBpNZeZSZyJOFoFUduJhjfxs2onKo3iwfjM7lW6Ey273opruhUaTUT2aiTDnCelSbbYzvcvEXLw4KzbzY1Osddph2WMERv36VaphNIS5fCpEe5OGcaNA55NGkXo6kzCU22z8Qpc9gbiQZoTWJV9hi73Idem8o00zs8vmPAtTjjgnVQIRba42x/GBenZhpC9aTxfxeLfRPhtAwePebU@QG550py1eSUqJub2@aA5ylXGT7V9dX8YqjTNPfBHST58ErXfKJ@b1RTkQEKVEd1IYz0KjohA/jV@UBeV8Vqo2JLEbrQWvlFN1wWTVWC@QkrjpZKqynnkkHc91pXSjpOrZhnAWE7UKz7Kz1q1Zbl3HL4KngatAbTgNBI3LKRuQblR5flO6uQl2mPTEuBi1atwk5zkzUze1flU4VdhSq1pYaPNiLmg0UqWMdDGezkfFuayHboXiaUapCDIHZkkk2q3rjcEiPWkzLWlWzKTjsdvgGUiQYSiJ6U2YFwVj1J312eLl@EyZ9ceDpu4Zztiq5/ZmFkn0mj2DFYrFeqkwzekR7dzoq0w0KgTPWvooZlSfhvNCxsz2mg0lnEk0u@3y2Q17WZcuEleZ2m1MjFTYwpOYaNWiAaEYaQksV9WGExNGJKE7YIrzQEcXFFHnY@PyUyQ3Hns688nY9IxuY6cX8VZ3kOEmAu8JpdraEz9rnisBuRQTu0a5NZ1c51tgIarNSUNl8reNUehCPpNqZ83y5YCrpKoLk00nWsJ1uHujc5IqTaohM3JeELsxQcrmbgf97FnhqRC4kZ4CU07Rr65C@TOOiUmetKl1FLZ5NbpSF0FeTN2U45fTziIz7JUk8awQzOo31WindsErORhG5adiYNTMnxZvO22lx0qaWq5VAwHmNhrMta6rT9ykc1VZ1LXZmd49T1WU0LVUULXKdZPLXulsKZbOX2X61dvMPB6t6EpbrHfjdXXoOQ1pAp9Si1EmJk7EdLPFNkQ5xMVmizY/EFnutjUYxM/YRdRYsCnVmPbj3UWifTrkWrcl7bQ@H7Cnw9ltJX3NjUUPx1WEEXNlLiqR09OW52J@2ih0lUZBElh@OO8bZ@mxeD5tX0VTnvgoUPfkOs3erFjpjlo5NtZux7laKNQKm0@dyty4KjHNbPEsFMvOzZmUG4xLs/jZKBWtzWeNq3B4cNufleO1aDUy4ybaIJce5bsRVrs2YuqsftbNp8WcdCkZl4u2MGSii3GpkI/nPBGRv6nc3AakHPtU6yhmryvVL65DtSgrRM7KlentbTbFDmNSP1dQTmFMnPKXs3mtfzNoX5WNkMxo5RtPIbqILmq3V6WOWmmdX/ba024sVtHPmv3EeHEzqspVz2jRKLS102xlqGQX1yBw0Woi0m8ouUZLvs5WA2XGjLZSU7DBuXRRnnfZQiRwIamB89nwNHE9bEUHN4NmZlK9mQ360Vosoo3FRcxsPUXGYiN2cz6ssUL7ZtrzBE8ZrbaYX@euwnqxNB0VzYomXgTiweLtoDHMjRueYeYi3zYzrcCoHWwVp2NPJgJWQfyymQiW2hf9dGFwemWcXQUTTD0vz8fx/mn01FOBwWTcN8rxphJUJmyLVZrTiTgYBvhSlm/qs3YjX@yUOsE4O/LIsal5EX06v6nc8uYorLKMMY92prznLAcWRFa@idQ8TXMUGMJcJHA9CV2o3VDQUK9rNcHMaLFBI5QQw3m9qWrNmdZvBuWr09hgKsgXfSYtLjphpVFtdUqzxbSTGIQ7fG3SSOWv1VYoo456M0PnoomLYJN/qgz1UNkcVYoNIa1eDXlemnpmSjp7qdcmTKdbSnVa@aexNGmGy6lwan7dCYTHt5M@py6uczfBfqWd6knTaiu8qE5D6c4pp1aH8mioB9lAvanmBvFZ40y8YM4XOXHei1@lK81w46KfGISU7qBWCcwHZVkSbm@NMVe46RavuE4h0kxfJQZnkpESY42EdN5nZ6V2@Taa6YjhAOPpFYZsMFMUQue5a495LiiRJ3nBlcxFQlLnpYbcrnUnqVGx02@MS@kzNs0FJ6ez8jB0VmVDYz49jGcv9BtdYcRcJDVrlC@jRu82ZTbDWiU4iY9uK3L3Otip9HhhGIjGQQdfdtq380aqmp4Wb0pnNSOldheiR59eqKeFfD6tMmdSq/RkPPGaNE6FG@XizdXTVUrv1iNt0yhwsyeRnc/V8nlGEOY3qYIxKDXPa2ohFhh20pexq16nqDa0ihy6YIREbHAdY9WacD4OiOFKKpx/ap4KT4VJtKoNVFOo5245s1QFZVeINMqjm@lwkekFpFkonLs2yt3O6BZ6a3/BBMdn1ZtOVeqrs2n13GxehIY1btCcKoOoyo884VyiXOa5bggnYZFrTR1qykXXvK6VJhc6y/YW0bE4OhUvZKYYHHVThWr0PMifnt5kEw1u@FQUg/HL8Dg1DZarlx41Io6yhe5QCWQG1b54JcOUoRWt9M8DtZLc6N6OM9eJeY1Z3LSlhHremmoXmcE0O5j0641ZCKZX9WbRMGrVa7NTmATb5zGlXe516tl85krI8LwRK6uZXHkwGjfbw@lZOML086Hr/mXsXO5GB7GCOL@5GI8SlfNFIdM7C3tu1PO4ecObylNZ6T@V2qbZforJzdrVOdtKxwQ18DSPmde9FmswZ/Fh7jQsxhaFHhdrqMPJeNwpV1WtMK9cXQKbY8FQ/bTNpkatq4rZ7JyJwvVZAyz9c00s1K7PR7XT67POuKMySgjEN8PqF6dFI3@dHdxy00J13pY5z6B8MS1HYhEp0fZMIsNSb5yNRFqx4Xlpks@O9OjsErR@tzKvFMVq6ZLhhpc3uYHnXOK4uH65aE7C1ZR4HW1fTqVpOJJNzdRePN4IzK7OT4WreHtUmA4b51z3ip3eJgbGkG/w1ZSgSWUm/TQKzbMzMxeI5C6iZ9dXYj867eTGwUJqWmsVomaiJLVa4adpdToQS3lOqs8m02AlX74y1XBk1ry6HVxAK0QYoTu7ysXEy7DYCciL24ye19pqg08F2HM2OG00rzxaV30qiZ5BJZgPjaK5wKzCw8z4Nj0@70Tbjb7SOk2fJXpMJyzkPHUjWriNPl0/Xcr6dd8TG4LKiUvVydUlmCRts1EPz66kxA23aGbiLb6dX3C5CzYVPjsbJwrB4HkxUbxhjFpkCNLyNA1en2eV4FWlWQ@PPdlSdtbp1W4b1cz0Mn57ww0rrdrkHCdjITYwlcr9amNeys8ashjNDao5Kc14CldTo5wYSdVsM6ezlY6UD/cHZ6f5U3F8IYxnOdUT6BYa88nTeCjGzy8VXtTVfNXspYTQTXwQmgmFUerposnMz/jcOZeJN@P6QBbO@6WG0TcmrZEkp8JPkZnHrPYr8kUkW61fq/1Gr1TShcxlMGaI2UFtGL1t9GftiZjrnDOSmZgIyuy0FDXV9DwvXzcur847tcBcqMTPS3l9Fmiz@adaYGKyjXitUu@2S7pc7MPA6blpaFpcAZVi9rQrhh/1CoFpM3XRiXeNzGkgXjyflRtyyRO4ylX72aAx0T1sb1gOZhda7jwkTWPd6tXFMKBnJp2e56ISY2/7aW1aYiJmJ9TijUGiKnE3N012lKsuDOMy3mh7Lq4UVqwGb2PpswVXb4dGnXHvJn4zPJ083dxcPrWbtTNozmuPGK1dPjHdq4szIyYlBK7TSGeKKW0yCpzrw6oUHha1m0bwRvLczLKF6VPwIpDvF9pcqdRbLNLCud5S49lh@zLDz/uNeJMJ5cqBzm1IHJ03sk83@d64L2SKMyF0rZ0ZnutwaTY@1eOxKBdOTHgj1BwOm554SpE9sVBv3gumc5Nolu3o1RaTK3syLU2DXlC9jfIl1gh3SoppNGL1Wi5RzeQzZ8WL3LVUTNQK/PW15@aqkMml6tHzi94gfHHDGWk2fdnr14JMv5gZdFjTjI/lmpw3cqd6dta7HVwNx@1pbFI0bhbqBT@Wu0NO4keDVlGNRVNXzadIORDKXbK524WiBmORWYLpCFLnnFWqg@tWXM6dsTdKDybQWZD/wfXlWBck3eglWlDzy4UayzTK3aZ@pvQqQKHSHo8EaZiQBz0xdMtU2Vo8H2spF5JQvqkOYzdt@bp@HopJ4xnMX2@yiwspy0KrN25qvXHgOpoD0zUcfiq0esOrSalpVCPZZr1YCTPNp2pW4gq5YrF5a3a4UjnQzU/MRix@luOEYXpQys3T7XRhmhcarTNP3xOsd4RJvplScs0Ob8zmt4FEQE9JfSbaj16mpSxnTiNNSQ9nznvlEK8UtFn5PD4aVivnwfR57krSBnogfZVaHtHmPDGUI/OulEqdNgs3mS6Tuspk@8GmZAhV1TMtULB0XuF/@5O3ChF1XaVgzESTO/g5HUO0t7k4emfjCbrzBL7evrXvBDr7bG4kINnvVwMtUI7X0cA3hA@tQuizTT9@agEfLR69fLbo45bbCdAL7uNBDujnFaStB6EOHTOvyPggq@8RQJ940ico@ByMvp78M@MQfkCDd4kS2ETfqHNR3ri/SBvlCO7zgTt3Bh6ONh55urhNapBAaDJelYCfXsfPcFeFbyEjfQScK@fdux7rB4628gNxxkilO404fH4HzWrvioGYtlFYrYnxq70ZGLohy/LB2jsfj@JZLh6IJuj@HkT1mt7hXeLBeyAkHUQ0ZV4dGmN92hl0td5EIgoZ9dszYb54IiQSJiEoK/ittasnF02ydJ/cGJzjJEG31t1fbqpJtxXHvbjodoq4h6eTkNVmVkcfiJsGvHg6dBy9klJyMFxKobXJx/Au@pBUk4Gj4Z36cKR6PG7TkzQ9nMeFEd9y7qPR2PZEvDMf6Fv77AG5XL5aj59WQN9fTSIVTRV6mtMg9HPUm@@c0D3Hlh1oyI82@9NEFExN34yRUJ744VZHfB2FT4n5FzllbQlnzkciPrpb7UqgaCC/ePpmHA0fvU7HGn7zDW6hcWT7TmxW4DMzGrcVWThkvqH8xEfg@Dr94aG9KYxAUG6/@YbGyVakRQuRDRcmHy1TBW00tzPLFsjjsi7HGyhPXPhs1e39GsglVBtk8hE/hKUDmAVisXcLnJzQDyqIQDKlCsNFUV09B8V9fNxHuMsJ@bBMW@74g/AoN3TfnUeTyHSXHrgcExuU7oFB3PaOEzT2TsaX3qgrwYnTSvqmPx6O6PNnv0WvzRH8dufjiJf1VU6/McbvZrsIh8yQl0RjC2DgGbd9m/CmuNk0y7ZAxzf68hXWB/FV6KdagGCBx4/@gm7Elw8QX0ejeb6xPg7rIqZmOVZaZNh5aTXcdlMD43AXa@fIeUioH9wRRNFHokcbqX1Ixbq@kTyE5CFv9t5I7iHusfFWsg7J@MnYN5JlSLbeidydrkG69aT/DQATvTxBXB9N7dHkZcVlbeiBW4E8WwrbRTyeJWNXIkCshrHaYzs/sbdGIR@s1rGEbUu8oH9SsbIAUKRddufB@7W00FTc5NtlycVGmRZPyGfyxcJs50hg8SMtCdQulu8@2MJPNgiA/geqlLxOXxZutfaqolvy44dhp4utDcwKkR9@eI8yWxC35Y97WEqf1ULoh7tRQ4tbazzWFy3X7WplWtiZduext47Z1G5LH4l1PZadMrhWIVbfWvdrSVY7UAYg/rAZjS5PbvJxHXNnPJDDlfZY89HqFl/mY/CV9KBHFO2RXtJeB4Wv5yqPcg85eRiR22tlgfuE8Uev2GmsoH3b0CcAveLmCzkTtmTG7qU/tbJfV5s9oI92asqbI0vRCmAantgE7iCPt9p1UydYyPadh1Y8fqlT3kYmv4HM2k/vERCYx0ADjmxLNb4cE2XVb72TCno@EAx7qYu5BfK8ZtNSWX0Nn/4JOhcyzh6yx/jxsm2VRHaw5hX4qt7Ir5OXXe5F9SxNv7tyd9ZLzc6PTqSRvJYnKnUfYZQ8JAGy2rjpiDx/WQ/9bpz5vG6@LXvHcP3/xV1tVxs5sv6c/hXC3CR20jY2yezO5W1ijAHfA5i1TRIOYYmxG@iN7fZx24DvJL99t54qSa32C7D3ftgzZ0K7JVWVSqVSqVqqWq4rzKAbSXyJCP5awuhnhSzdhfVLleI4SGDN8MySxEEIFy9KydH6K/PGHLuUub3UAgNVm@ly0CwATQEZym4rX9tcO4nq1NEXr8bGuPETKww5Q0UqyGTf9Fx1ju3cPi/e7lsbOoo54pbgJjsszJGhLLwxti2ZwaZdoXOFYRYmg580p2@jqJs1BpM2GBiCidBBlXwJZ2XNKjEvE/SEThu96lZH@TDr7ia9WdGveF2hFzA@tWyCiHe3PG02MW0c@yaMOaUtl2M1IlTm9gEOK4r2URuz71HbmkCvFjYyGh8xyThypdbzvBKn1EOm0h7gYCiGQ7bWWxm8twOBOju00U7iW/IY/FrgZZAYnjq65Z/u1iXcDAuwie2gm1OQuU1LzdZWBmiswP/65@rK2iQerV2Hg7VgcE9G9fXUW1XBQBKxbajJ@Cb/Ow4KlxsHn7U24XPZfAiRxIRGCtgKg@AhizpkOSOKaCbnSUw6PrRY8hB@mM@N94L7Lln9ErFlGMWP/O@UNgvFwmQ4jrhEI@LYdepn@DOJp1rkW0R6x6DJ2WI4SZ0s7hfI26mclcyXxEAqIbRyzgFxgZascDPfMhmMHwjV50kvLr24ELQ7dyACsvdTtlM0XCzJv7zYDD1irYEVuLxCjz2JMjHks6NAwdZJPOXf1H38LuFB3vARV8i93qd4fCAYJb0oGkLIcRQU7beIAcL4V83WXrXRKOikNnJiHafc5RwzrghywDpOqmCP8eK0OsIFyqC8QmcBW/BtJ8BZ/zKPgFazCVPhAewUXiEeofQgX@Jfc92w9XNSnVnC1530rxi8LOqoHkOyo8C7pFnWaZY3zUxlhxWvnuVGu9NBIIjjoB8RxZWg1yOihRevEnbgERwx@N9b/PEFcF5a4qU8P1eeT5UXpFyISmoVOnejpNKGWymz@mdS75fKJNX8OVzbijpdO@HoUoVo5NC9@VTduECbtDCpvGOHUqTSFmylCvJOyd8XjL6UrKTaWAG35RdSruV7XY@8pTJV91MaP/56eoACjsGgryzOSGlhEPb@EPejLWENqxBWSZpjvFnsZFJqh4hWJ3lSEyTEPG13thMo70tG4/CcyexsfcoUtEvqj@wsGZKNbW5iLZgjDpcY53tm3COvJISHi1ccEAwTgqbMzN0xjae68dQBi1orBq1nIoWmJzh1bXaKb@NY90/8YyZ7mjhTb3Vx4Suh/FE6Lzct0gxipbuSWcymtDYZjyaBvNSdemIVSXBPZyEuVhInEXagnTtoCoszkPsgN9Fk0F2xesJVFEZTzPHdlmhOJxVKRnyXDSEKf3n/XHvnHbT7ZBX2gkdVhk3d5kj8XuqyzTiIxzHNgYA6OFLxZDjshTqum3rg6xw6hc/6b7iMkEB0jIaCV8MFUanv40lfjqFGBVUH5AfcM0wK4sktMlrDE4zkzKRab0ICOS545cGUIxNzGLR1ufISqAniuEIB92jb5xAhIyezhz0PsNIKnrlYJF29kfk9GJMJRB2POOYhQq1ueN7fJmHnR@VArReLfy0VP5QclhlXdbHw4aOqOSaSKVgvlorF30ofPa8SDadytTHbyQHWxzwA@uoIC/1nks3gHsmTvTKtGFwxJtM/Dkb3QbfgeY2gyz7g6wlzBKI8iQOJosxxXvGGbCvEuydztx/7irZdd1Av@Iv1WWLXdjiwhu/hDtEwGPXDsdw0iu7DLhho7k3dRL1e9MCOaFxZEn6gUT8YE1Pe5VSaJI5Lq2lh24XDxRI3kNOBA/hdR/ccR1qzgezUEOH3@QKQhyCKgOAikwTxDiWEr9Nrh32I0wICEGUp4YAhgLrWnXSCJ2nwmIh/kwalO9aNOhNE5m2bkVkj7RfxXKHpHoxC0r4Jg3lUuJlDOw1w67DWVM36futLuVFV9HzaqH@u7VX31O65ah1WVaV@es5pu9Rh/Yi0S1OVT/bo7UmrUds9a9XpRabcpJYZLvDKJ@eq@vW0UW02Vb2hasenRzWCRuAb5ZNWrdr0Ve2kcnRGi/WBrwiCOqm31FHtuNaiaq26z1hNMy9pp@r76rjaqBzSz/Ju7ajWOmeM@7XWCZDtE7ayOi03WrXK2VG5oU7PGqf1ZlWhY95erVk5KteOq3sFwk84VfVz9aSlmoflo6OZjta/nFQbID7Vy90qUVnePaoyJu7nXq1RrbTQoeSpQswjAo981TytVmp4qH6tUnfKjXNfA21W/3ZGlahQ7ZWPywfUOS/7DFdoXCpnjeoxiCZONM92m61a66xVVQf1@h7zulltfK5Vqs1N5R3Vm8yws2bVV8jEyagJBnGLyul596xZY77VTlq0Zpydtmr1kxwN8hdiDFFZpqZ7zOD6ifSWmFRvnAMq@MAD4Ksvh1V63wBPmVtlcKFJXKu03GqEkJjYcrupTqoHR7WD6kmliuI6wHypNas5GrBaExUIJvB@KRPSM@41xonokkcSVs9Irs/DqWr7qrz3uQbKdW2SgGZNSwuzrXKoeU5zec1b@MntyQ9481/5tCvk6SDxlfpelSw@yQyTSd6f0aLze/rjXaqMFhpbSD/1V1Beq666wfXk9ioc3ETYmttm8gW7H9/6yISUQx7Ub94TmZ71h3JusLp6dfW5fEX73ObVVc5/ScsUGc@10FFYn6qV033sRe0ub/NTviWXUTtvdKx3XwIvu76WN9b5kFNra91AN8PlRQA2biKdlICAdaEZ@VZje6AclPyJOe0r4owZs84i83kziumfwc/kh6wNzgtSznJuYW0Ne1gmA5lPlKWfkHBSEJ0ZhM8BhDeMshAHwY/bbNFFhy2/dlDlTBuuO6Zt4G0290zz6@B2pnl@tj0Ti7umbKyYcPAmTDsEM@JfmmVKj0thxD3LimuP/@QMNYyIjMKcoOKLrPr0SfaNNEd8UfEV5jZtKHFOB3Jc/lr7gs1ccf3j5sz7Q/te5hZunSO3Da13F9zukv8cXkoFmmAhtl/EknAqn1TX1pw2ZJWxPWkrI1b9HSo9hF1aU7FU3wW8rCNCvoQLdtvTYjwKH13qSQ0fNMrHu2f7@6Q5Qe3H33/76182PR1xfzT@6svfc@BBbkvmLlnRDyGZaVzkzJIK2T37c8lynOw@GD1URJ5IM2j8sk0mrY2cKTaC5NcQNxC6GyPDwABJNjJIEjDKKNzPD1Y8I68LZ6YWgGyqqzn0pt9@ZAu/TaYSy0BHomT2pjxqj/gHsO30N1PcdkgLkBaxoD8cT0lyaXPBei@zbwIO8N6GrxWjSiFj5HjYNmeQhDHQmRyFAXfw@ZeWbWcUya7FQGO@8rBzSyJiZZYKk6SFUy4RitMoNjNYXob05quWN3o818mBUIRUD@Vxk9i4b1vmTfIe8TnriaEhX@5s0xC9eWMxbSk4UnOaKPH/p1PHuLOBSZEDDWoGsDl5ZPlsS9gJ/eltTv0pkoqo3oCzqSVW/ybJXdQdDWXThETXv00GGSWwkoQy/OrB4vBMlXNTxbIzxab/Fz8Y/n@QJwvgb9GGk6An3GI9HA4mwQs5yVCFV7R7ZaaED@bEmHNMLeGm@@o8AfPLHZg72zF9DO9RPiwRC/ToTM2Lc0kpll3AAAg5/Bru/EUAX57Ed23aOX3iuftKvvSPBp3@MGsScpmlYg7upc82l2@OyOFHTj7hF5WD7gj5VT5xnEfWGdhwkRa7nqrXcUZgvC@xzkGn196x08POchZNsKFkZngiTkU9tczkf9QnjJJVpmtKf5EpujzZl/0cgpxCKYVvvoAYBcJnn9wOa7YRzh0QurDfiPTCXn6lV3EkpiQVyOuyanF4jrh9w3tmLEU6lgaCdgAl4Lzu6pxN18H4ActFT6BzDJEEmsq@5jAmQKJ9kdaMMMo3VyCu8yL7YKlnNyXk1VJ/NvgxQIrkQFxcpkYhlQHKDcFaUMdtTgbVe1m/Mwny92DrThp/bcBxVTryvRKuOd65Exbs9F/HCUfI4nyAdUnrUMKlducHXmaMjIYP@fCR/jCuvO65yWlEewbOWLfI6P@1dEMAWZk5A6sy3wbWibQhC9n2a2O@4Enmrn06x5P2M29Tp4g4eoMDs9oMAsmwm3BIc362MX2psDo4fLpBltPDQ@G6Pem3Bzftftib8qnTf0R3g7V4MImHheHUy2QyaW8gAoEjRArRPg7Ul3DQjR5itUvTAY6k5slZ8zTt@HM8XxXxfCn1P4RD7TJmbw78DWImxdHNmIYm2FRTnWN8lLh72E@oPS3s1priBQJTjViACG/fWsYHJ2fqIBgEI7IHT/nMpToKO8GA1AcZU3wKM74TTYPq@8De1NjVPmwX9uxsqiBkp4717XkagYbmQ7SyNBWJ4JFOqwjf/JRE3fEJFuY7nPSra5xKd9FQRwOC0xTGprg4byY930Puxi@11iE247IxZ98MLWvG1wdfophOfXHWUmdG7cF4SkzxZp03RPZzvpuC4mBABNFbzk7e1PWRYr0Lt18vpq4iQbzWAryC0FQNwnski2M33EvGiM/ZardZwrdNHV/Rl/R1RnWkRs9LRs9HztCCr377b9UKILvqtNfu0A5LNSdo/uED2YG7UTxG1eOyUsX1UqmUL32Ai/asWS7wRMD/JoOY59WOT@uNFjFSh8g3gmHXTDCfk3bJaSxiRx6pu6j336GQTX3SmOvfmXkwwU0c38ymfLHIbGRo7DttuHuph3HaHGaXLFzy0YgThyEaFIlQajoSVgQ9QIo@VpLA5ED3OXWZTj4mS4ulk6P5cYPvoK1HctXD99Dv3JjfkQIIHvkdtRrxzqCrw97TmPSDvqU@HJvVvS0VvNmcZ5Zh4ksl4Xjrv4WVRNzLuXC6Ac5IxMge0I/vOyPSLe17EjkcYTEhsUhmWDflbG/a12EvpDlAdHXuIiw4oq7MQLALws2I5vGI21w7WJCYlgXZCmh2daO@rSpUeZ4NBqffD@NpJ1Krt7TNxk4rHgZBlzMlTIaSCgDlBZrlPVo5JEzcRpIjwFst8rnJESkbpGQh3TfpIXYsYv1dy5h7pjckVSa8YOsO23oBRD1qjnmSImNbdsEO21f4zpvjYW@TQKBtDoxYEuiPQAx9fJQiqmi8WSD4icXFRziqHo/3bBxANORkRPEwXQBY8lU3SBcY8Oi7fpyrIEK6bQmYCTFoiJE4WfKc8oGlf6C/OHeKoGlZ6SN1bpqzzNwPkUJTfAORuo3wLyoXDMfkG2HA3wjnAhc@IiQvwZutWZqvSbVsAhGn5voCmPmFMD8shpnXMPXHytrgngO2oRWLhfRCokFHpB/BiKT7B5FRvRxWrhfJBybb@9tedI28TaQpCBv@TP1kYN3XvANLMdotlSCC6XxTW6ZLmnR9t8nYLmqL5kewo7aMx2Ln20AGShdsy1zimGWK1y6eTvyIf/SM4sdMKnkVrI6Z7FUgT96S7gbYjAap32Q2VDIzcRLHra8xp5v0U01KM000cekm16km614SqXRmdNECqh9/0z0zdgmfSuIRUNt2gIpev/0ou5siB6BjNw1SRqYi4q1fagFBxYuOsjHtUP3SS0I0pz7bCw7zk4/g8YnvzH9lOOVVMZ3v4NEc3WM1wLVS5VMOAz7I6g7lNBv4hw3/nDPE6H5tcZOBo6lsh6XAS3V7hLtaWRdLbkOtDtvy1RC1YixsLuoL5gG@0mfov3cqqxHkXWKlEsLqalVIjOfQyxe0lZVhMXqw6CUrM/9yFByNoCf6m4@MyTKQzabmldHcFqY8zuluAoX3Ao4xeRL/Mya7Tt5iRXFUQxMGH9KYaiMveKTtGX9jZhC8/liPtX4pMY2t9tDEXySYL82qke7F0tqzS8miOs6qYrnwVGXDbMunpZWXrzbMOvgQoO@kusO6IziJNevMEvw2FpaxlRKOOdhp1AlFQ6XZ5ihdaesvUMDpITfE@TO98pxQ5rqHs8uIl1o5U0KSdX4hTbt6LYnsBFDOS7UC/5cNOI47uhN7ab2S1NPDvkwiLCwz7k@Jha1sxv0psZDKzrA/LRYml6FlLbeflYvUSAgLcChR7xjYp@TqIFPw6NZ6nKnFBE0v3VjmQS@7gFpHq2pfpzdnKlkW6dQlaRz851EGZlUHGk2JIzHvwo7GZdJbWuM6P4Kujcise2@3SDuZ9JIgozmbiACdNhh4jC5zSJltG5DGFieY3jP35ewmR7R/KxsW3oMia9ftXfp2bwqsWVWKuXmD0kTvT4jfWkh8fj6LQrLF2pjPD29Pl2mqceApGnVRO@Mt@OLrPUPVe4eqdO@cEUqzeAmk/Isg5V8Aac2BpCf2B1ov@XF1hDx1wXMgvn2bh8F//k4bKQ2DNG03hBMb@@CH9vQ5mCtkbK3ymbq2nCqzDRI7@TkYf8zC4Lygd/ZrnH5514bX7X@DUTSblWMpZ9OysoAiS9XqPFk@yGKtzftdXc@YSry3Lfy4vgvtTmD1@ZGWOMa6MY4S39mPQKvpqPoWWDL/S0v45zvDmp4PQnjKDUPWsvdvTocCGCEeJrkqZhs4iiy9D9UFaUY8XTqr/Hi3Ohv9GAlPlzbLPduTT@LwcZxOJeqaaKyUxJktXKKczGpl9Nui7dmz@FcX4h9GQ7JxbhYSwPX78OOLU2pGpSem6czW@kVr2cL1bL5frt02k5vk5ZP8zVzX16nruJhOk3oQPOjV/ynIui9mBP4PlvyFkZElRL5eSCQ@tLe1c0sNJv3rYOS9ZKpLiwL@yB5pueR63uqqKndoy6wj48Mr1uH0fYFGCTMYghCryRDfa2I53InJDR9ZIAI8W7cbPQy4diEDFOyj7QftgQ6VrxfM2xG@X9i6PtJ34nIXYwgHHWJ0HDjuz@@Sk7ob6BKcSH6CrZuLxx5SDZyaCj/BpMkSWzM7Te9p5e0SA8daNVxrY9ZQMbKDj6HvxDLX9hIZ5rnFLrCXWE9PGUQkxMtQ6g3vDOinZXRjOTMnQ8tKOzQvYOUic8t6uV9gbk1fam79Bzg5O6Ce86ytB73Abjyr1GY3@d6/AA)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
140 [Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
142 [BitChanger](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html)</sup>

### Explanation

There is also [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_(programming_language)). Thue code is based on Hello world example:

```
Yo::=~147
::=
Yo...
```

All lines before `Yo::=~147` are not valid productions and ignored. `~` means "print". Line `::=` ends section of production rules.
There must be only one occurrence of `Yo` after `::=` line.

**Retina**: Removed two blank lines around `#1""/*/` lines by adding space char to two remaining blank lines.

**Incident**: Lots of small refactorings all over the place. Removed Incident-related tabs. Moved token breaker from C++ to DOBELA.

#### ADJUST

Refactored ADJUST, it now uses 2 lines to execute its main code:
[image] 
`K` turn right
`yy` clear the stacks
`a+-` push 49 on both stacks
`A=A` print 1 two times (`=` swaps the stacks)
`gRA;&` move to upper line. It was `}` instead of `A` initially, but Flaks broke and adding `{` didn't help.
`g+$` push 51 on both stacks
`A` print 3
`C` exit

Comment: An old classic! And yay, <.002 VIP score!

Answer (score 5):

## 148. [VTFF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/VTFF), 6343 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\D v'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(  >77*,68*,@'1   #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz( coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    /"78"oo@      h#115 o# do  xxxxx-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOxx4O6O@ 0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{}))) \';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+---
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
Yo::=~147
::=
You can see an x here.<<110

>{-<<
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ-}
>main=print 146{-ss

set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"1015""6 27""ing-?"ye
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );return 2;}int z=0;int q(int a,int b   ){return b;}main(  ){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999   99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x            A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _@125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

[VIP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer) score: .001956

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4@bDnH@RLbdn3SLIeJPWWbXlvPW3JsiTraflxfCiKlChRJE1Sz318kcEM0p2kMdN9Ox3cTrpz7830YAJMfwh6ZoBuJMAA018b@RHnazCY@w/urCqSetiy9z5J0xZZrFq1atWqVatWFReLPc4Y/u53B/hANVVeDmTVRKZgmKivSzNBD6LMEn3iJCMaClMUhkrrg@lEUEzjmDpALEKSwkt9uEemOhYUaSXoEB9CSNPVgc5NkDnkTCQYPKcJBlKnpjY1kSruzxZGKD9RR1IA55xIygDATEHXdMEk6RGEWorMTXp97kVK9EWBmg7pBsoJ8g@TH0zEq5MJp/QNgIwhlKtm8uX0CwxxhK5U3RAwHl4wDBVHJhBa5AX@BWgSQDldUsvpyvmLJJZB50A6p8nCAnE9w9Q53pRUBSexqFFpNWovc4RQu1ko7MQSRtd0tT/lMRPMoQDJmHGiJAsGxUMFz5BmN1cQB9AB0gWub4FRoqojnAVNxjKSEK9pqCdzwyCPZAlgC0wCCZjPaAXp8tBAC20CGAx1ImzTYSBFEPrI0AReEiWelI6EhSkoBlTJCCKJH6O5JMuoL8iQYUMS7wdkaGpsRVkEBKm@SiE4eO1FBdZ3hwLAKILDBEEDVmMmqLhlgCMOL@Y6p2lAJPCwAYSb0gQETDLdBhI4Q8IiDFkMQekT/mlr4VYRp2zXEs0kDnFA71QnuA1Bxy0WJHjRUNAFQMmtxcsz1yUTWIDZm0Y1gdNRUxcE766g7xQJham4BBNXJEia7/TUna8W3NCMVo4gp5nUgR5uXpcoDgVT6PDxBH4pl@uEyldy6PPhPQ5bcg1NrekezotSP0cGfX8vwG/B9uiB/kwBVgq4IiNa1UyaC2hAYMAEAmkOB3EoMAsFNXmrYHT6oi22hMuC6kNroKKC2n5SM36q67jvbpjKjaHSsqoMgJ9QWX2qYH4oKMZAE/AqdD0/EmbANVWx2kidEw43hxI0moGbZKu3WBqIMBR0EMiezVGnXEOVpwQOchomFkDgCmTFGIsiaiORk2ScBdIxKotqXTCmsonzTJU@bnnQMEI/iBwyeLWPgSbqDIrjACmJgL402eqBhCgAhoZQSVVx0o//4s/7gwHgSfO8qvdtcW2jvsoTXckRYkEBISywqsLJhCyA8@PSrexQwIyTpT5n4uKVpV0EIYKUOlench@pUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITcUq9@NOHGlt6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodQJ@y0Eq8QB0QmQlMpqaYQAEtj9wG/Z3n47Hn44d7AYjzBr1HhzQ9OAGBCx6RKLhzvyc57fSO@jNMzlClPqUtzaGqhFCARy4@pWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q1ifebxnkgpPihKSt/jBhnPQLlu7wmf4u@k44eTF7m3SwQsc4wF91bBw3tdFGgc0idm9ISTlKC2RO2AHdpKU41HzHGcHNyKxnx5GTezIg7I6ILFUsXyAWooaMiCoHmYIOvFWgLD7a02TthX0Rc47AofSw8@94Hbt111ggFqulNR3Febkoq1lqwNp6CjgSmKoYH21rHo8hwIj4GVuAlDvB/1iFgTzQ@KhajEueDWBdQDPeqIEemRVo/D@QNYT9oYNj3Igdvt0EJ/qz@DLoAubRqvlLKszqFgQhsevkCDKLhwbgBNBJmtCqWtClklkpjdqo0V0CsYW09AiUBPgr6Aex2odlv0t@oI4OGQBQPYrL6ypYIm3BKw8NaQuOk3SBKhS01AS@hLxAtY9YAOEqxxBRcyJd3QAOMGmzlMIBSN7na1Vz3N1Ol04BZ09Yp@t0Phym/3KaxvkCjMkcwpgyk3wPaVAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30ctghkQF7DA0aQ@rw08uyyVhij65bZWBdb7WePSJyWMnYFlZABp2KONtGRH1JB@0kL1@WDgCzF4W7vscgOwR873qDBMcQACETFgI/NUG5gSDPhxI/BNnF1CmWerTGopfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aEwMe/ZtiArS6yhMxpsoArhFX@OBMRajOtuJII2/HfE@Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNkhzQZC9L@CcqIq6Bykwco0Wg@ymWO0ABlkDG4MwfjnWF@msawtx3UTQZqA9oOeD/A1NUzOOYbiQzOG0FwRJoZv6smhWFSwstKkvJVO1wj1Z7YF6NqB/0k4JND/tSYsXFSJx6zYcGdQM7DDRQCkYwJ@mIHUet2iA4iTxWQy8leQiCpygsM4uACRAQWCURzSISi6AUmksFd7jCpKuFIRO5/IjF@64Li8EcK41X7LqBGsh1CH2ATb4MjpoLhG0la37iern9o546zGAmHdud3CkSorns/vDhw/uY/cZaPgPHz5C6BSHPuKQD0IfSShAQhguiEMkh5@EcOodyYHjHtzPdw7mhfcBN9sCj04rSfNwd8fH4Qc/d8fa1xC@ekHVgWYD6AC@AB63N5XCQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbqJKtVc/rGWbl6kXPTU0GlZ6tEKjK@PE@jBMJdx7ckPkxInOwTrqmqmSIPheAJdACB7ZkeZ6hT6PMw/pIlkFsnsR1awYG8azUnNQrkbBDVJMCl7NNrIOp4IbdoG6kHgi9tzIlFXJ2sNZ1ACP1SR6zDswrb8zuQVD/t2agSnTu2p61Z8HMdP8LQzyFMDnkcB1bpdR9qACQyIp6JBmMxRA58PQ5Kp6TrShkwSlHh6GtR7TuRnlnnG8eu56dY4so1xX/rbmdbIWYLcUKaGtlW5z2yIxM9MUcRdlLByz9zbBo9h2L7aE@RFLBIQZDFoLlZBrEViEcq6oED/LYg9eanFal8GygSVEFiILxI4nbIobMLQVoaZDCpLBlmq2G59at1v7imX1a/Du4OWa5MS2liY@81i1zYWIuMgN2MVa9FN6BFswOgOCpjVv84pSsaQnHZAX1H0OoXkNiY9kZz2ABzbphb0FDzvxywp4VkjtvZUFSnCnICRQYMgA1ZJCkfXyQUPH/vo2R0Id4jpCeIUZpJ0T1Jw@AtggWSCQIq9nvQWKPAFk@5c94Dp094@toFwDV/ZSmiH8eZUN2Whb1//6@/3oQFeN8@QW8IMiB@vA4/AN9xUAfHN1rKz4hty2t@yBGY0lSWOsIGEvoSS5/AslZPXgf2osaZGgcCQ06Fxl07jgnDiE3Tpd@TMolwX5GlfcK77CyEs3rXIrNyKNCE1gis2L8nw@kb2F/aklR/P8nVZ5foEi7X6Igmb1rbaRVhwA6gcvaWRQHF@BZ2O2Yc2yy1g35hT64xXWL7UrpKGf/u5crwrZEyU67ECzE65nvQGHzEZsbck2@ow2CIJiDI3toKPOLi/slZ1dGkwAEvMvr4FBmY3zIw0jhfoObm8IxbOGIHI@M@9h1OXrfNbIM4K8jrwFiBUVSannyJ8RBx46CFYdvA6Z2CLTdILxspcb4ktt@FPlyJcIBl8QcmkeJ@PCeNxeD0x3qyoatrb@bHhQPInk/tzW4uvBAGviqIgfKnnwugjTTg5EOpvBd9UxI6luwntAR1xMw5sYJkzQEhMm83CDJqFnN4TXDyg8FhcNqF3xHZDjrP@8dYUepNHk3hVlgyNNLdz85ZGfDn52KDBy@vktMmK717ztw/2Ph6sA@vQ/k6t8iaexr4hR1@hpKwZJJ6jbwlGUH2Ld7w6x783zYShOhOs8/6Ba7WXqq9QQQGZSAbMIV9n7/NfEle8HkpO@7k43kuVyct744/RlarqQ0ExUCjIYDNHIYv4MGzLsjWlbRarb8u0IcmqgRrk/B4vYJ5gGNZ5vzRvs03ilAA/tPrYOrw/216iyCCH0uT8RuNy8kCVY4kBzcHpTQmY6iLW9Pb1azXcWkOx7Bc11NroURXWvr6p2sfw/yXhIMuzOl612Aq@Y0vtU2f2bPftCsK8AC9F7q9cgUmQnEHamty91QA6P5xzS@f6Dxg93uKuM3poS2Iyg02HMyQTEDB1y4z@h5QWeb@0/tfpqFdo41@qxFbjjmUBNDY5v2pSFGLYn5iDZZiv11iiPBWmwl4NUu2NBBCb93TH1xPF2NU4tJdDaGAefnK7hlrZE8KvohqP5/juXYXDyRJ08i9aM3tVjQZ2toYn0DUI1HDgdcaBMtV2GneLd/WpUn@fc0PN6dlqf4dInPJTNVLiyzbTjiluCOT3ltmen6gw7VUnYEMoX9H@NlKycmSddxCTmA3mkYQXsfR38R6j9fIm2K9gj0CrSmMjgFfCvk7xhN6arxPgZBJmZIpgLvH5LW7vU6Q9VZV/SuuAPu1L2EwD4xO7MHyplV7ZPvZKN9qsTBh4laMnvrUmYY019uQRuIcnym82dA2qZJLB4Wta@dXS4Duj1tZC4ZfmkDBik4UfQ@ed8Fv01nHnZoOJYPxdgp1VMdoJvIcsGQx/jX2kOUYvWYfFa7fWau3GB@Pghf7RlsApqR8w@KEwEcjtOxY/1x9NDefyJtBCxb89yUGarKS@kU@ToMMr@LyzMrxlEpmqIhi0yekDAc9VZIEDa9SKfUvJOgu0e5lbnHADofBFydosO@BnoLwu7QT3L0AcW48leMj2BTViTQNVZSwsDee631he8tCe08m72PZ1ch6vbn6xVwfpvYvSX7D5lKE6VIbCUCc9Y333Vt8AiTQtn633KgH0DzljjB/6EoW0meMNjW3uyqosfw13sUK01KOq7l94zWNnqz5k/Ul4l1wPEuzLF9foYNwmTCID@Ft9ZyhMYXgyVFPVhAC5ewtUxis81nn/WnKx6jZQRxL0Pq4JlsUJFC31ZAHNJSBhZGw/Hdi/etSTVQ77FbxjwQNnnOvXrEfxqr7fkjvnVBOM0/dH3AKh50vjckYysQ/A4AuAO83TEzhTkca03b/t2/1yvKttSdUkFMjh6KAsATP0ZRC3cmo7vYEvxf09WyrbvpbvVis71fXll6XSHE6tJX0ceGtpxX5W9DrZfk5I/MrWrgeG33aIgzhJt92fjLWP4UFR4XWBOCI4D6bRAXaPmE6mMmeqehAROI@H8/m8XsrKhFchBgqAOVDEywu7flgOZAaSJcMksJKI7u7Q4efFMXPMPqMUch270MODhZU4IeQXGnHPqltZ7w65h9ShOxBwH7rvlWPEuAmoIMOkcC8otwMnSuRi0bmpOlK4CfE2wWGnpieWS4sxJF5jIHZ96AgtsGrICpaqW44ZlvdPEz@6@C9/1bed6WAYM9BEMmASMFCwA6g6EYbq/KNVrl16WtM47IyHccyHeG0elx7IppEB3RiGbeJDp85Rq9BM2C45tosq3NTw4LVFhdWo2KDCjmKm1WgWNX1VsETLLnidy6kUr8rTiQLKo28OjSBqgEoRiMvP@iEthDCYYupYg/b9qIj6Al407mPCiNEgq@qYPH3GlPyXv7IckSBRwiKEw07xxA9xq0SEDSHi/cPz6hSodpCsBF21QTyYyTBwTbE9Dh1DsOK9iB9yxEMKJDHg@AfhYiwfoWy6gQJ55MZ@tNjr4EQSPYfp@nn7jnlI/RxNaOG//j7t/WzzzfWzQDxmuPzIATl5xnK1nRyF5E2qG7kOFy67WthjkzgoroXK9tX24DBpLsffZ0KcPYncCXPi70Meoyt4XMZelIoB/QNuvQS11WlSh56pZfwFGiaKYmdjsKc4CFnuocRvDvuu4CyHC/QDGmJZCfCIjTJwZzFExu5Sk1TGefAX3n42S@eE3pQ8p5iFgqFwilTn8DF1ekZCutBXsffi3Xf3ixATuF/E8w@04TDn/n7xMyZ0A9xTYVw6/JbGHShfyX0@DJ4xP/xgcEvkcj27T6xn1dDLDz/XirV8o5luthrAzWersgcFVZ9wG02BZUGTOR66j0zcQoEtuiQYX9Yeaw2yvgNwjwcdcugUe5l7veuENajNalfAdWgF1yBgoG3n/kL2ffkNYSv9NYCtmUQJ2VoU1Ygg2TLjNrY1qN@RLdwuuLtPQWc7HMGOA3tUIeGRC6WASwHg0lfyCL2updWCH0kENOOXGfU@jn0ogFcbiNcAmEnrsnB9rXSrcnsr//zfoMYajGv/2BoTHO/WGEO8V2MA3GQjOQrpYrlVz@9mAnHavAMARrCO3/cQSd@yvIkt6VJtz1VHMxH70bA91Na61UAzySD2JZY3EY8MMEUj3ZE8rjSwdkFYkQVRWjZAk/f7oJp6SxNrNlDpQeKiYvmpBBTkOgBmBdcDrR@5KAxrpF57MILmmvOgxb63Mh8SOILZoPZ4XN8L9I//4s8tL@t7E8J/aIcXTAbu/ti@EyH8z50UloW7f7m@C8HdL6y772jMytc@pVZt1kzEDGwXa8ggJjBm0YRbbNUej2147JQUMNukCfB6RliHwa1qbTizweO5awPnobmA7VhJY71MyhP0Bw/2CDymaWyK4EWLIHGIEBY8MY6Jg@DTFPvHw1BCx6KxCAs2oxCYOQgDkoUwoFkIvd5jkEpqJmmp73s8Oj09RS6D52QhFTuxWE4fct@FXd@vCT0EWMqyWu4Q5IEsmxyQdmZn8xxyPtaLs@LO6Wbd6OEEDBKrBWFM85AAgHhxtGLzwwWDpmqzCsRDERYmUfxLxxoDU0ghjl6C9ZaEgygAiCzc2I37pZRvnrNj/6MtuQ9uN4Org8EaGOzYtU/I7r5D9@a98mB78yMQmF/vETkFwn@0x8V/LT3p187lnpeu4bg26FNDUbHvRQGoRZ4QHQrTbMy71adcNiqgF/egHwAl9Bnog7wgjVTNSGfzxVK11njlHE0g3S/B3Mh9duq7DwT9dw/rgPuF1DtMzRToxlWm4LBym6rN8iWG2KxhviRzX2kvKX2j9I7l4PC6bJLwqiCW@VrEZL0gUCDL/K@xb1LpLcCs9QD2Vake7@fnu4fTs3vl4FXxP@x7b@QgeISFC0L3BnlrxI326Jyi47bRxG8AGkHHDzDk2rwVtXaKtO430W@7N6/fJ9z4ODsOIti/OXRG94UZrUxlmQq@4ToCdQ/SVlHEwdcizKEXdI1DKotJ3RTIU6@WoLepQXZdXr/6aPt5rplUtSay5P0NToE5jC7xFrRBFLQ13SUvG8CEp2hu5kgw78LLhmQquCTTHlAV68fZfYksnnG646O5TmkIEynQdOjBimPjswyKDPviDqFustQ74VJ3C7R2g3zPnTloaLJkerAf8SKIp5NQG48XV4A9lQXshnyafLB9npHjmuwj3s21KfCrpmpoM4XPCU6oDrM4lJsCchADAZWmE4ATyaUu4FFCQBU1AJmBj26HiDsoxWPXITjpR6H04FBY9KUBjDQerx9U0s9YduMXzXl9MPV2gx62WHWOn9NvM@Yn@XJvcYy744KS0hcWHvzezvED5g7Eu@edmdvreiUDxKHc9i7vv/Qsd5QFZ9q9duOV/UIhJJNrRbDbd5LJ4NCgsJsqzECgxIaplyEIY6hHnHAa8kyJa76Bgojceu49it8wdS8KnOHxbI4U5PORuQtcSEIQkZwiCUkyXhjz4BfaPHQK2hnHGkofX1aShu7YYPABwqQQLzrEqw9ZMDfwvN1LgWkKWY4JWhiA4e8YUzSHWRqmyLoekmIpvHSgA9TeZNKRB0PSAYEXpNbo7Fu00QabHmhxNZk8tltjVx0mEYjF6R6NAWj3qDnHNgX@2r6GwDWsxAAqC5NSCRTKp0tBUaC/ekBmJtA7ETcFIdO9fufVa//mRT1SwoFF4oXtvAiE7r7Al3d/llWwZw7pEzIDPnmGcf/7ezzwi/bQv6R/jw7SJ589h3JqSYMx5j3zHA5TrC985PMdKkeeQwWbI99@iyfOz4dg7TwGXUHXAoACh7L3BOQZrKPUoXJyyJ16Dvup0BHJAbc@n/czZPi5QQc/H3LP9OG3YE34IUa3eqfn0PDi7sAEg@wz0Id7yCHtB5n57HEhF3lxGhd/KPl8mIbg4SMm4Of0fcNHxpX7Bk3m6Ce2kUsPJo4a2bVV1i3x6kVwi4F29PFao0eJE7r1fOrRAd5@f29P2j776He/O2BjMN36GAt71I@h8IejA3TwyUUfuXTX5/scmrnvODEUfHqojWu1G@@9B0TSfZCtutiI6zuEjmjqgD5ifojT9Pfffw/WJ7o7C54FH7x3AffDnQehs3j8yB9LHPk/uVky3YapG8t6PaGQl0b3DXQf57gjXyT0STnJ4@Pv/s@/@@Xf/Qn5@yX5/Q2SJEkz@n34qUM0Ris4xiLC/yS86m@FORzuiSsPfh0VTLkUFrNv4GBrbnc07G58h99G@fgB/sg/HOtbfP5AYuxoAvL6@OBFnqcFdXDGH6wOWJY9WJK/Rxxm2cW@43ErTLNs6F75Bu8iEPvw6RtgmeAjx/HxJzIPcsUTLlX9ZM09h4A1itQDbMwjkj@AD@pg0eTwH2r28F/dxH/tMf6r8/gvM8Z/5RX@20cSdfDzVMr3U49g8NEJUQffn36f@kccpH5AB8xpDs7OHp6ffYG74HcnvpMT/MP/oA@c4Ak5rBAQ8eAL@E7vTk@DZ2eLs8DD2R118Bl48kwdhFwgvPdH1EFqcVonlN7lzmyan@wJfRnCp4GHu1oZTPGmP3QaOAgV0ll/qNHKHLBwF93c4sQwvq3n07lqC6Br5Xy6kT8vtvOtGsQbD49nnz75gtAqn4A7Zw9Ay@JnvjNfyjRNdPt4FETvHo97QtYtdZA7W7TowCmQW7Zj6qSgwD3c3XuDZw8/UAd3B3eej6GPIUZmZgw7ZsdXanXzX60uFpFqrPoJQbq0YEaqzgyZIdsHWUWM0GKWzHLBTNQq24egAH/MBIISIy6YAaMwCsvu4Hv7f1JVr6oqoFIhm7lgTIyVEeE6qFavAJkIBY/gT2IYZgGELpgZ/DMy6Tfsd48MrqOXub@n7pDrewEUSpB1Bxl3MOZ2Sw/RmPb0@TkUe7oj5kY0@XAnLCTzwYX87sf7u2Qy6X44OaCN@3va0rGuUMR1gkGenx8fc@lm@vGRxus0i9ND3ydf4BMcqTPfqX35eNA/O/l4fxzAEm5JefDxgD79eH8WDuBwzAd8D0HcKf2Te80aJVw/3FNuz7zT6eBfZz6bWyESsOLuO@tUfOrQEGWFcBQcGJTel383sHgtbB7PXfTh87MXpu/37hO3xSiPBwlgo3tc7P0iJKKQy0uM9ySMfGwY21exqPfsLBaF@1jCG/AwJNnKcu/SNO3eFSSLAUHiYJVKpXWdWxKgCAy@9y5Of7x33YUeUqlklERHA8kYUvVAMux1eb3fsaendhkhL0S73AuXqrvR5@ftP8/n51MPObz4z@vFkfb5zOuBZG8U7hafPYtTz6kHx0EUzvX5@QwHCdxnCN15vA/e52crDs4e76mF88wLfMMrHv8N/1UDGRpyHzwfYKNJQZGo19NbCt5IzJPwJe2/1AeogMcVdoehXi435767@3QUPopH7j4@HD0ceU6Pgkf3Zw87CtzrPkDQVRzRTrEHmG/UQfCk7mJDLjcW9RP8kEOVhaCsDlA4ebIrDO5Hz9HLI8EmfUe@T3dHyaRV9tHRDx@gVwI6KMwFxwHIL/Kg07PTtVCtMS68ZwD7GdlMhvDzZ5AzKxFsMI/9GOP@fsFYvR2d9FKHnw@45xOCHz273Cc78krwe9wn5DmX67PrkNPv2AfXs@vwc@8ZG6tHrJfYRNHIyclRxArHExBmj7zW0m2UgTsnDCmCwfFEMZwcYHFyA8@9UKtUTxhIChioO0zyRaNROgTnxc9i@dCCOsHPg6yHT66Ay@pAKJEk@A6QYSQpmA/1oOXnKM7AqC3jl0dUUfxgxcPEDvUEAWxrQZbx8iSe94D5L/fnMNf@QB2AHgMTyxDgmNQ4YSoI8@l0LqyPrGQccyPkGcG8HR8//voPfvz1//jjb37x42/@4Mff/PK3v/rlH8Dvr@D3C@v6i/@QjOLzb3/1L//XH//iNxD5N/D7z/D7T7/91b/5fetH7v8Wfv/3Vtzf2r8tOOtHAa4//u2v/uQvf/urf/5n8Pt39u/PXv5@/NP/aP3/P/YfDv7mxz/9W3yyb/7gF9Tf//Wv8f@f/PXf/@df4///7X/5@7/@13//x/@eBP7cCvy//@4/WGco/Jd/9OO/@WdQpz/F4X8KYfhHvoB1@GyAP8SRPxwyYG6i@x@2IX@gWRiBEL0V@Yfoh3vsvspuIAH/v/2BZmCQZCzINc5tyD/67a/@1V9C7A8wvrKsDfnPnOy2DO1ArunEZpxV1h8C8F9swfzhj7/@/R//8n/48dd//uOv/5gCuxn@P6APVAjhKz7hSBIgocURFQ2DqDphdhMOR0g4Cud9xgd@8PPx006UhftoHzAB/EjSP@y1ZXAZRw5t@wr74OTfi@Ej@gTJMGyRkWuBz/gGYnCYaD1ycaIWNiC5t2Ds@62cVox1j7ay78bjyK2MzmVftJVAinSAkI1sYReKNujtalAOZRbw4lUEhezqUVQctWpwqhfPL5pb12Y@nb2gYihTreReXKI2UBSV84Xm@jZupTpZo2sU3Xy5/PLWvnTV4@PUz9lInIIr3E0Rz2FtRTaxWJBtpoKnpyDqFHX2OXB6Sp018k1IaFYRG2KC1NkNWgRRrXYdeKbO8GpNylKRbCT2OWAYFIX15wcUjfv9wWAQTvjqJwe5Bg@/c0DYty3nAxdMI6MuVwyF4i4X6NHAR9dSoK7wk4oka7mYSBgNhHQhiR@qgy6eK8SnoYf3Pplqb0fCBUfhoC4NhiYy5@oawDAMMMHWxpljmK0NtA7qcRz@/dQDShC2D/P9CNMqg8S9SpFfg1MXMCRN8CYE2JvNxDN3SUQMFcStEwolE9FEMhxK@BPJRCTKxqJRPxvys/FEPMn4gdkJNpaIJll/IpIMRyKRpB@aO5qMUweC0pdEmoYZFwtTL3yVFB6/RXuKX0dWg8Mz6qAviNj9Ai08fS866K8jpgnkCifuGQQZXWyMwo9CjxYpsNzxQ@Iwi1gX5eIQjw4KhSxTKLhcGXwD2pvJMi5XH99EEwwTz7hcAknJJsJMCDIN8V0@xuBXElwSvsmmCwWMYYRvQgmMw@UaWynWjezcxAFMwTfhMEaAXK6nNToGkKsWRQmSy7RuGCaTdbmmFnkJ@AO4tHUXIcTm8Q1OwJkKVkoW0lyucycTDEouV92Cs4u6cOqbTrtcResmncYoSqTyUatSl/gmTQ7IpMMdCK/LNYDAQAdzw@XqQRCLsMvFQ4hfchA3gRB24VVMzuVaWvXANXG5FgSa48cu16MTD@UAPRcX3NDsCwPrWOrWlYekIiRJi2m@0Ds/7w0GPX2Zzp/XSVKpdMGNllO9N@jZGXuPcKg4FySNJ8uXh4CTHh85eX/SJSQpL5Iel48CofCRewLK7GOAC5o8lnBSCZL2rYXYCOGYAHAPH5kJXDNcz0pyDpJErotez3UCQkvh3oOWHu9nMiv1IENaCaB0PIx/CnOl6MdpwhWLu46P4Or66ApDcOFBjBusX5f73uXy3iUfPrriUdex@@PHgPtb9iNyxZOuY1c87kLeE10wp7qCQifPuJxVijnB1ycPPnN@fO5hK/qzDdc7ecYq14OjnjwrX4r1o5X3IyYNZncwH/YeE2JPnmn6FGsA3GXhihxVTZbVATLhCoD@RmsAS1Ws@zoKBEB5I/iBDYPTtZRVb48r6UHYgkVwvncRA99a8PS43fGQ2@11nwCSD8i1pcy9JxbRFg89DiOwigdGJGE@avPBkwzAbAkFklCBVyTp42PD5HS8Ak5KPEauWNKFo/HWikmnsE/@AOs/PupFT8/@yavjv/sn@479sfigrLEtxlIHz1Qfv4kbSaKT5AlejYJ56emZXeglWi45X8Ch4VuEBr5D6tCN6@0O78zT06n0oJ525kDpLHUQCKsR9eDw8JA6OG2eucKuavBxvQZxRpO1rHu8xIVXhoL3j6cffP@gBYpA8OyTsxoHhNOULmA/sD7ez9FaJ0hEcUsMkHHg@wceUAiVApzUCZ5Jug406H28jJZ4zRPdWxU6/fkBWUdAtc@OW85UIc8Dj6/w0x8Pd9wgeyTcPSDvzyuS/DkRDpyR5XMs2QhE47mR/C7@XeK7q1a1VS18Yo4Tx4n7e7v9/aybdZOmefwEY5hUz1MHxg9eNcr@XCmdHBxr7nDEDeb0ferAqjYb9x6cheJBg1sePNjurJ5IHAs33JNpZYhFB2Jn95jv3MwmZBUSikr8Xn8wkEK/d/X9D4c07XaDeX949vkrjue709PnU3w82wF8en5@Pn31Ty6b4w2YTfo/TGKCjwcPsZ8HTq3/UzhlqxZ3XLGoy4s9lI3vHr97PABFkkSuUBT3eh@NrJnr9jzbszhSvjtS4E84MsifIJBb5ej0DKIMiLDvBQwheI9omr4Ogd2STMYSsQPqdzT93jN7SF0/xBIFQTemk31PsdK6dMXhJ3zK@kkWBK6mK0GHq7M1pGPhIGzi4Me02MbZjrPNnq0osqPqbtzSoLFPIY4FqxjvvUn270UiVqUevHJjEt8wdIT3s8Wu017qM/UN4JryJnFHhNMJRX2D/eLwrceB86NvDdOLPYEYL/XNN/bgYJhBw3zEyHEmOzLAnlDPFGYP1@8bCD9gJI49lr81h73MVM16t01eIiuTQQY5y1gjrtK43C2Cj5BoUQG1OUKkREI5rpxV/DcWWG8qYlIKxXIe8qAUEsmDaju3S@/hnctI9T6IXrtwxEAUxoLBCacIOAYEdBDpIbi9E@zUzXsIpA@xOF0kD7wBCmxXP6HEj0Q74x2@fYDsGL3Iy6oBiK3SPVYN0NGjXaxdB2fMxZUAFuLakXGMjM36gPfbrYf3fLl78KLPjuuoB6eiUxTa@LbauKAxrE2HSUZ@0rcEh2wJZ7OZYGMf/NC0J5YLomcNZ8dsGPVMHZn@yYnVVNoJdenhvZ/xA9GTn0@@/Zb/TrubPJx4JykTX32@CQyrY49kgRyZqUkKxEO7kx5OzDufT3pITbyXHnwPIzaYIs@UaDHb8Np1g5orKaAFO00YXv/qTgn8XHnwF@4UH5A89R/dplZ@LsX4F/CTwDqR/U8p1q4HlGmmVj7lhDuFH342u@PeCSaGjzvZicJZxh45tbrjHlLADxky@nwFqAzQadzJPt@DFwqXIfF1xhP52285n3y2OJEDAS@G@i78sXBnQuDBl8L3xx7udPFxdTeF/MceuKagGNkLxEM@m9fPa9qBvhPgsdWmG9ItGheYvAWQN0mljm4/Ht0epT58WN0tApMHv8X@Y2YjDZj4BSb@ZMt91nN060UvWEJWUz2un0nHPwseGcjll3w@YLJf28ppUXh0Cymaz@dQ/Yz1JdkL1XnujyXMdvm0to4ju0mR5XqyZatBtqk2@9j5HfKmDV6SbHDrrQVNgvkyhzdX9SNFVQIcgcBp9t7MOPF@8fEj5RRtexlCyVi59ATE4Xk32ZpTx0u7ZJ9v64WiL@nXfWrY0bnr6WajeJtHMLMNx7a6K1FNpMMZOn@HQbAa@Mw8n1gay/ItBWVDtAfAEO2B4QJYi2Am2XrChkzZidBaTgNBLqwnROuFKrwZmYH1E6i3Tc8HFWKRAZ15DxmSf5QiugnkSYIQkk5JeRCArkJ9A5XANOA6SA/oDBQZ@vZbZN@epmC2HsdjAQbDcCMfi4FeUQqFfwWlgANTOQIZxfqQFAK0fYNTsO/0TkGRf1xB9qsPHsjgG/mtNyCC5A0Iz1QxrBd/MN@8Fhm4Lb75ZuRLRWyC4J9MKyA/pD3/7sAe7o9RtnpVazXz9at0A84wPUpstn8@Xm8U/Gp7UA1v@9mTFOL/y3N1VuiWeDBhwGY18XZReBvwPiq1yigUquT8eHMHYP2BtYYGA@rxGpNgkI3zjKCqD@i5NJbo3a8K4C2biasx@YZBwNm/GZNDBmd58zrS5m0kA695wWBuv5G@s4P8RDAMe9fTgLORPNksn7yYNcHvF0EvtHdJJV5cjiMKcXvCTzX8xJlOlwYS2R18aCHYyU82tDSt7KR/UHh30z5ncliiqWSCYY4R48cB1gmEnEDYCUScQNQJxJxA3AkknEDSDrAOZtbCDDPZcDi2CcY3wcQmmFwHI8wmuMEQCW2C4U0wsglGN8FNaZF1abEEwYsOHG6SrivoOI2NJJw0/EqiYpLIKKBhX0ZGgNDQK0jIHnkVCeUldiPjScYuqEhXMVAoFNvcg/ZxYFMeiyq/RYffKtm6syNhrKKsORoR2Lyug1bKL/B2ziB03mOEX6@gKFC7iJcFDowBwQQrJVUA@Re8x9Zrh/ryePOKBcaQYtf3kB1vdwp5WLIzuSU@e5JD@5ItbKG92Kx3P9GaMVvvp9hEWlQe74y0FsbITtw21g9YwWKOvgERsiBwG@y@0OKU2dSne4sMv1/kDsK9Rb4iysIb3ZcL88ZDkKecrGT8J9hSTnmWnSKQ1gYzwP4MBZGBFw2K3z9NfWaPXb/91Z/97@i3v/qT36Af/@I3/99/@p9x@D/i0/8BNgsKrQF@8Sf49G/x6V/j01/g059uZSLw4WPXj3/2a7j9n/49@vEP/sRK@ld/6fJH1oggBUdtcv7yn@LTP8On/8vlj64Bf/lHFiDO4vI/UzumlQegfvE3CEFpGMsa2Z/9FUIuHxgYHlvy7qw@/rD1tpqFYM2GOxJ6eJlunfmhjtnOeH0uwGvfsZs7H24A7xZyncPfVdj0PTBnLN9nrKV5jh/iN5LsKNXA9g@PTRjVCA5A3uZ9MHrstQ031P6/R8fI7cMwEE1eu01ZOtyuv11v1yYVw/pcNFCHtyq2UeGwd00JTG8pkG8yE1gaQTxtITNS1pIRm78V/N0WZwBxOZIlmR7WS9llOblh0oPs7e/hfzPVxUKLhyHrtVXyGQrKfmWG3SpwR928aDYo5WUMTBk3L7JtZyURwkSDJoFsa35jxuIbwgX/S3SblrO7Tb5aeNFh8NEDE3O8rZHWBaWQy/UFWMxpG96LLa7wLrxFrw1wxxyHH3Zei9sH7Lq5uXFRW3EMliG97yEYtiplqYx1ErubFNpKCm0lAc0WTqJroqHQCxrIwIH14u4roFa2LRW1m20jXLjnOO2AyYC5oLWa6RflqTFMvUZNNPKusnuNfAsl@5Cy@8m9QnTOGXJ5X2UAnLt5Ui/bcj9q5hXM64banxNzeydmp7XexrSTZ6tTEO5RL7m0bjk2ua/ldgt8BzX74PvKgkLMP7KgwFcWFIt@uaCXzYrz7qB/m79fVjuOmlhr@A0yq@Mf7AxQeGj8MxC9jTrCFOsk6PHClCdtT3l6cxV59nznAOJpZzennY8b6Ft7POFJTEU1BWt54JOmwpRDxVbw1seR9n32zP4W0UBRdcHYft1Vsl4IUtz4hWteHSgwqvnxrlKS/eUO/BTe2p5jd1xZj2y2FZq1vreEUVuMwpbn46OkSObjIxifsujdMBDfBnn8loabwh9qgtBWfs/atK1qHhXvjmd6v4yT2LtWtqbEjz1VzU50QyFpBBM6XpBh8oWGHD/GnxwjLMFVJK@UYou0Z3q8mIlDdaIOBEXF75rj3C/QFze4MUGcphFa/IjzI36LInsS7eH9nNfOevmTs6LLkIfzrvOHdhHsMMOP9Jc8xpzV9xT3@GZxVjanvMZPp7exTW/jfXpFSTfMlzSTSLzag68/reiwZ4MBADdkhL9Mht/eXuIVOTukrKPx90OsDF9NYl8weBj@MKVpAE3b4EER5MO/vjPgbk14@y3@v9@ATvb81zYfMWYbS9A3kzy2/cgUzSAb9Ci84AHwohfrntfFrUU795Vl2RMdMsPzIxdRXAp@2Qc6pqYJirF@Lu0g/oLMY/egV3JPfIZSVuIemvSZH41DbzdR7rEvyNxS6HtsSP8WXqfGdYHrE331dRXHio4oPdX6aIyH8bM7phh5KZMAHb8hMpx/5vW@LVYWiLSWHvIwjlBYfJt/ZOHupWrGi6Ap6xmIqoMGPSD7tpDdcrSltrRe5Jatb9XZetQaf6yWrOD327/IEOCD9SUy1r8p1vue@qx71lX6ihFhDRvcrTJ@V9PBiN@WfN2GP41FX64pWWVYZ0o5rbxjnbzV4tJ7Lb4lFY5MWlbJ14nkl4Tuq2VuS9QsZBsVlv1pQ8grzFlOlnnes43Rinm3xVTllU7AcbjFVOWNUeVxj0Jd5ySazsS7@6cs@8JLSRAswnUG1zZcMUKYgz5aAuXUDdu1zpIXSZlw2pbVYsfc8dgW3eKid/s54hYU5YTxQu7zukz@zTL5V2XyO2Wue8BukVtAFL9TpN0KuHneawJZEM03tDNOwjN3uLyntuFQVE7Hz14/uyX3seRH7pn7GBSyW3Af5z2glN1993GOBAz3cYMExu7jSwhs@pb7B/ex0y0wgA63JPAJx9sqHN/z7uOsx/tMkS@UOuUG3cfrNgWYj9Yt4ciztbzas5/6q@tVVUHwW0alH2GJMeCi4mrdPfjJj4F/AmpvhgaJH1IodESA8QRkZ9DYGjGscmDYCJJPIHr2DR/HztKUvb6xWUOBdF9qa1EFS8mU6CP3gXtXGVmE4VSy@AhXIBDrzeP9FCH21czsS@TYpYOEkkbeLZ9wL0jsgb6HpN8B8PYijrzJ77TXLgqrAb@OTpz5LTpfkeMURyjCzgDePWRhpn7vfqdSuK1fbKxltf52C71eI8CNGHBArFYiaLd0Othw2DYlhWmqtiskJBU/7ZO28@DD7pRYel9kI1rB7plvJJNou2ZYMWx3fu971dnKh0nbUUE48Y55sHrZelwguhgnbXTdlqVqdT4gYUvn9MlOFwIW25wdJHCWuvGTseKtYcjJaxVJNNeumoTMQfwe3pQzrdI3z2Xw23k/bfrq5AQTHGjECLZyrkux9Kv6E@x31bLfHYPaYcKLAvYZ1vuH0tfm9buj7AvK5U2xrxsQJ/pRzrvXOFqXsGE5zA62LPP3ZO2ViY8/@mQZ@Vaha@wvrH2Hbes5wRf49nJuYeHCVoI@240c44XZcehtRr22SORZ0DFagrgkG49V8TWlm6q9T6tV8X1NjFPwGA2Xn9zA@m4DbzcexkcqoL9gudXL8Tc1yXOKdd/Ga@pbTy6spw4q9hJbbxO3FQnqnvivrV20IKL6WM9VK@UuDLrxeNz7@lEE7rWQdzOOU@8@JlhPW0J@vNMP@dI39p0Yqrr54V5xvXYpIxFgDHDkuY0lfnYf99q6bEufv@i7kM@C3eKojWu86QbcjlbCpg6Hh2zJ5qu14bjniLOROOYt8NtPZmv4qRGWDvxA5/GRDF@Pj9g55/HRHsVw06wfI/3uwP7mWGjrc90Hu95MxOIyXm2ngRcAphPrY9H2Apy9UYblh3KAP8xuOrnXuaaKKTnODnh9CD@iWntGeMKs1/qeuxNjfXYdJNUTiuApbCiKX2u2cmFovPBJXCvtcj5Yhg7eL9bQVMX@LvtYUIjZjnevNZylV0L2VJlzxA3EKoW8jb1FkeWQ5TwXI59aJlu8W9@15hRrCdnhjR8JgyB54hNKwpRjLGnWRnBr1w/DSzIRgomPFvC4JwsT/LljkN09q8lXErTKsCANBiBItL2LvuXg0sRfQA6oYiDrbHBygNrko9X2Vpu2TxjZ5tZeBwZ2enZ2qDFQKAbWVNIPnN38gLHYTQbhXWgY4qRFoOAXh0vcCib8W3k/eJbe3SvrHF6M74PnEbes9RqnpOMd82ecssVn@@3OraVp@6El0QNbTy6dzZYoe3OsFHlOGcQ@aprHdeBytqDCQcttgpN5Z@8WD9416Jj6RiGKB3uAId7yrQEDV8FGG3m85l27pCroZygcIp8AhfKIlUqKBRzWk70d7JAGWTGxlnefrWBcP@u7foYfJlLfHGBdaMkazu@IMg6TTTc3sow@2OisByq4K1tdwLmJbt2EYarxzZ6CP3hcPsDic3ldO5gA3n768Y2leV9nBaXo/R3d7Mc6BTWdTjcnrF4/Tw/Sw3S9C/cZpuzrjCJ5ms5fyP10rthbnqvx5kwMMc3udaYX9tXi/YUmXUyyF1qekiLdie82vEheRFbRbDib5pkb8bwsRuLZG/HGENKykKRno/F1X6hrPVY3pMvKVaW@ogut6/bgeiTedjqjuNKgtPptZnC9EK4THWXWbiWLxrXQzlbMcWVkTtllNd6JteaKkWk3M8PSsjgfL4oxtStFs9dCvC1qF3N@GdX4ixZ1O2sOY42L5TjJTvrLdNbod@M@H93NZgaJC75/K5Ya2cv@QI/2ouNGkgvPJiVRWw4vL5Sn8ijbmPE@bVQoxmaUUivO5kKkM@7JF8ptvd3u5TK1@Zg1brX@KNK5mpq9hB4Lh6dpYTiKRItTU0@UM@nLuJlLF9sF@aZt3i7biRplXpjNeKvEJ2XfrGry4WmuRRtMe1GSLhvz2EWoqV4oJbk4qo3Pp@c1WZuOcxGp2pxE9MFNoaeGQhfXjdlFt0zpkVKnm6iPQokcv@Dpy6iqTsLNZKWsXy2mmaeq0MnyjYzQizGZ6E2eHV1Vl3x1Vq7XOzWt05rEjUtWvi0wI6p6wzfSmXGhPEmwzcqymDgvNqbZbHEx64XEgZqe9jvhq5vYvFwRip1rOnzBTc0rn5StyvSoVDKW7dZl8aZi3EK3vipJEXG5yLQzuviUyxpX9TJd0cfDRmSk9LV2XMqqfKlWjJjFcfpi3rlNFjNjQaz1xuq42ZE7U1PKjegCtcyOr1s9YV6QVnMuHym3r@lRvs6b8fQg3KBHotgby1VjNTgvrwaNaW/QT1bPmZzwdNnPtKP1vMZeFYxIRVlS3WZGlFb1a5Ed15IXxdtePi1dKdFsTdBq5xezRSjUlcTaPLpiFzejQkRa8BGmXM3cXPmuS6G6r@zLZGpquDqgQrnCeWcQvfSpBWFFl0XuKZ716dNpZJGb4g9cl1uKrE@iMpMoNH3DuKF3kldX855RvKlnO7y8Stxejcex2zp1Mysaqh5KlArpJF0bM/o5N6oUb@OSUojMM@dyPlnsrFoJM1@eyomL8iBXquu55oS/SeYHjeVyPEiUhFp5nKaERK5eH/UG7d6i2zBqS@Yqwo96vvx5vvI0gH7cbhRCpVYmNpjWw@3LnDKrNQu@lXrTKWvZypjN1xLTWDMenlCzRSmRbpiKpOXOr5Kx66lUzqdzg1aWVQXh5om/ZMdco7lkEkZcvy7cXGuGz2z21EhvmAkvr6@6dPvWMKIXEnW76MSK6bHOX/YXZsmIN5WQWr1m2Gux0pKjs4701K2po/SEvmzdrOjefFVY1EzebIzVaD8eHZ8vjCd9dalfUonuiJNblaxaHvGxy660itNRVml2s@IV3y2FmHRrcHElFC5mg1VLmIRGF0/TC57jjVq62zuXY7OF5hPDiVmZalY6N4P40xPTEyrdpJQet@q1ohlqcvS02yhHn8pdwyjwraKUiUjKNJfpno8n2dsl1zQWq2kz1pPFZU0PMXlqUeletfmROjAKxi0/Wt0UbpWraSh2Ux2JcbM/ZicSW26LTLyi1X05X00@7w2WsfZUmPFgGWrXRY3NpEejKlVlJ/FZZpk0TOXcuKz0sqW0lE6XE6FrLRS/GGfPLxZ9qd1qVy76nBq57WXDsWpvwIT6mUp@UItMBvFaJR4pZ6lmb3ldZ/u5hMQOOTk7Ki0jWrIcysTo9rx@cT1qDpWKnE13FmImzDfVebzDiUpLWMXi9BXjGw2TJSXNRGoxqmXmzFa5MA/7lMviVai2XPI3PW4a5sSnruHju6vhqtoWOFUelp/qbLM9LWel0agdy/BNppppMNOVMee0co1K5moKmysvZoX5sNFhDC13oSV6i0o/W6sJPa0f1sReNb0QmVmnc3t93aoqk5vryUU93quu@two2jbFeqy6MKknMHnas3Kr0FvkREMc1WdPyvlietOmI63zSbnVn/lGydvuLCzdVJlyJdMWuWnxehA3W5WFdlWSRZmehKoDmpq3aquVKaTVfGV@1V2I7dUqLWWMJ3ZxSXPl82LuxvQl84V0rtpscLpcrZ6Xc2luMr@al2/iPmHVuOpHpfHTLVVTFDmk3zbkeIYJG6FWNLfK8qNzZnqemTRLzSSrsa2L9tXVJTuU@Qkf71Zzsc4V30mnS5fLksi1azWtdtlqUlWfcnN726SrTbmcFMvFelONFmf6VacT5@Zq@ppjipFJb15eZOZX02lnkiz5uqbAhdWVILD1uVymhQuQnQQlTGe1bKVmLENPq9HTYJZTb9rJtHYeS2eXYn8mzFZMOjfz0UZhMe/HJC0RanYX52KXvxoMLuuZYVibac1YNkqVkuKV0u5lh1fJpXB5UW4XpqbQ6Pciks9gtFHzOt0yWvxSOudjw1nL6MrQ@UQt2sxkk4Z8m0tc6pKPSfAZiu9ccTW6PIzeVEp9dZ5dXLWXOZhyJFixxkTVpdKeJsbKxaWRuew8XSYSg1bvYgwFT4e3Q15q@TL9nnAtyhXq9uayPc7Xpm16dH1zFa@1LnyJVVg/f@LV4TmXXDZXVYYRxORgVpwuwlqZT5wnLqu8XFpU6i1RGMQaoWv5XFlROSU@ZNIiO5/NFdq3jGYS@YGYaVUUPdfiL@KCWuNoetG5Naudm8Rl6Jy5ZhqTORMyruY0I3YVadmtdLuhPpWZGZdap8HO8r4LM91tjOr8uUxXOvXiSl2W8yGjla5kxcvpfKmVl5IevuXL51m5xkssmCXR2KCpt8arzKxHdcRFOZtJxG9DFyBBhiEn590IJ/CGNliM6PLV9EJejKbjtu6bLOi677a7iCaH7aFB8@Vys1Kc5/WoWjJGChWL8aGLjq7FjfrTZFnMmrlhuyVHssn2oFe96NJXTfEyeZ1t3MaFaI0uPgnJTiPG8OVoh6fZujqZmTAi8YMxVV4yfZ2XBZ2LT6tP0fx06usvZ1PTp93Gzy8TncE4y854zhdO99QnbtEuyYxUiQsDo9qZz24KHbAQlfaspVCF25YWvpQuxMZFu3o1Zmvp@sqkM8kOfxMZdHVWVMRZPWxGS0VhEOfFXP52PMpdFJ@KTFd8YuasrF9fhwsXLBUXfRlT7ct0@1q7VlYhTkh3q4mreX@VnQwronBRDOX0bj3Wb1xych6GUempzGjtwnn5tt@Th7SoKtVGnWGo21go37mpP7Gz/nVt1VQXF/qglK7J4RuxqKi1mzabu9bpSjxTuM6O6rfZZSJW0@We0BwkmsrEdx5WeS6tlGNUXJgJmXaHbglSmI0vVj1uLNDsbWc8TlzQq5ixotOKMR8lBqtk73zCdm4r6nlzOabPJ4vbWuaGnQo@lq3xGnVtrmrR8/OO73J53ioO5FZR5GlushwZF5mpUJr3rmNpX0Jjmr58vz1clGsDrZOn471egm2Ew52I@dSvLY3rCtXOlS/C8dzSXIj58bSySFxo6VhjuWhdRyLj29GimmjE6tEFO1PH@YxWGERp9caIK4vmxaCQEfLilWhcrXr8hIqtppViIZH3RQWuW@veMmKefmr0ZXM4EJuXN@FGjOajF9Xa/PY2l6YncXGUL8rnMCbOuavFsjHqjnvXVSMsUWq16yvGVrFV4/a60ldqndLVsDcfxOM1/aI9Sk5XXa0u1X3aqlXsqee52kTOrW5A4GL1ZHTUkvOtjnSTqzNVyox10nOwwdlMWVoO6GKUuRQVprSYnCdvJp3YuDtuZ2f17mI8ijXiUXUqrOJm5yk6FVrxbmnSoPledz70hc4ptbFa3uSvI3q5MtfKZk0VLplEqHw7bk3y05Zvkr0s9Mxsh9F6oU55PvVlo2AVJK7ayVCldznKFMfn18bFdShJNQvScpoYncfOfTUYTKYjo5poyyF5RndouT2fCeMJw1VyXFtf9FqFcr/SDyVozSfF5@Zl7KnUrd1yphZRaMpYxvpzzneRBwsiJ3WjDV/b1JgJzEWYm1n4UhmEQ4Zy02jwZlaNj1vhpBAp6G1FbS/UUTskXZ/Hx3NeuhxRGWHVj8iteqdfWazm/eQ40ucas1a6cKN0wllFGy4MnY0lL0Nt7qk20cNVU6uVW3xGuZ5wnDj3LeRM7kpvzKj@oJLudwpPU3HWjlTTkfTyps9EprezEausbvLd0KjWSw/Feb0TWdXn4Uz/nFXqE0mb6CGaabaV/DixaF0Il1RplReWw8R1ptaOtC5HyXFYHowbNWY5rkoif3trTNlid1C@ZvvFaDtznRxfiEZaiLeSYmlELyq96m0s2xciDOUbFid0KFvmw6X8jc8s8XL0SVqxFXOVFJVlpSX1GoNZWiv3R61pJXNBZ9jQ7HxRnYQv6nR4ymUmidyl3tVlSshH04tW9SpmDG/TZjui1kKzhHZbkwY3oX5tyPETJpYAHXzV790uW@l6Zl7uVi4aRloZrASfPr9UzouFQkahLsRO5cl44lRxmo60quXu9dN1Wh80oz3TKLKLJ4FeLpVqKcvzy266aIwr7VJDKcaZST9zFb8e9stKS61J4UuKT8bHN3FaafClKSNEaulI4al9zj8VZ7G6OlZMvpm/Zc1KHZRdMdqqat35ZJUdMuIiHMnfGNVBX7uF3jpaUaHpRb3br4sjZTGvl8z2ZXjSYMftuTyOKZzmi@ST1SrHDsJ4Eha9UZWJKl8OzJtGZXap0/RwFZsK2rlwKVHlkDZIF@uxUog7P@/mki128lQWQomryDQ9D1XrVz4lKmi54mAiM9lxfSRcSzBl6MRqoxLTqEitwe00e5NcNqhVtycmlVJnrl5mx/PceDZqthZhmF4122XDaNRvzH5xFuqV4nKvOuw3c4XsNZ/lOCNeVbL56libtnuT@UUkSo0K4ZvRVbwkDWLjeFFYdi@nWrJWWhWzw4uIr6uUEmaXM@Wnqjx6qvRMs/cUl9qN6xLdycR5hXlaxs2bYYc2qIvEJH8eEeKr4pCNt5TJbDrtV@uKWlzWrq@AzfFQuHneo9Na57pmtvsXAn9z0QJLv6QKxcZNSWuc31z0p32FksMgvllavzwvG4Wb3PiWnRfry57E@sbVy3k1Go@KyZ5vFp1UhtNcNNqJT0qVWSGn6bHFFWj9QW1ZKwv1yhXFTq66@bGvJLJsQr9atWeRelq4ifWu5uI8Es2lF8owkWgxi@vSOX@d6GnF@aRVYgfX9Pw2OTYmXIurp3lVrFKZJy28zC3MPBPNX8Yubq6FUWzez09DxfS80SnGzGRF7HQiT/P6fCxUCqzYXMzmoVqhem0qkeiifX07voRWiFL8YHGdjwtXEaHPSKvbrF5Qe0qLSzN0iQ7NW@1rnzpQniqCb1wLFcJaLM8sahzMjG8z01I/1muN5M555iI5pPoRPu9rGrHibezp5ulK0m9GvvgEVE5CrM@ur8Ak6ZmtZmRxLSa77KqdTXS4XmHF5i/pdOTiYposhkKlcrLcpYxGdALS8jQP3ZRycui61m5Gpr5cJbfoDxu3rXp2fpW47bKTWqcxK@HJWJhm5mJ1VG8tK4VFSxJi@XE9L2YoX/F6blSTmljPtfM6XeuLhchofHFeOBeml/x0kVd8zKDYWs6ephMhUbqSOUFXCnVzmObD3cQ4vOCLWvrpsk0tL7h8ic0m2gl9LPGlUaVljIxZRxOldOQpuvCZ9VFNuozm6s0bZdQaVio6n70KxQ0hN25MYret0aI3E/L9EiWayRkvL84rMVPJLAvSTevqutRvMEu@lihVCvqC6dGFpwYzM@lWolFrDnoVXSqPYOD0dVuqmpBBpZhD9ZritGGRmbfTl/3EwMieM4lyaVFtSRUfc52vj3IhY6b76OGkGsqt1HwpLM7jg/r15YTRs7P@0HdZi9O3o4w6r1BRsx/ucMY4WRfZbrdNa/n6yjCuEq2e7/JapoV66DaeuVixzV5Y60@H3UR3cj576navnnrtxgU0541PiDWunqjB9eWFEReTPNtvZbLltDrTmJI@qYuRSVnttkJd0ddd5Irzp9AlUxgVe2ylMlytMnxJ7yiJ3KR3leWWo1aiTYXzVaZ/Gxa0Uiv31C0MpyM@W17w4Rv1wvDdRCqL6bmeiMfYSHLGGeH2ZNL2JdKy5IuHh8thKJOfxXJ0X693qHzVl@2oKvSC@m2Mq9BGpF@RTaMVbzbyyXq2kL0oX@ZvxHKyUeRubnzd62I2n27GSpfDceSyyxoZOnM1HDVC1KicHfdp00xMpYZUMPLnem4xvB1fT6a9eXxWNror5ZKbSoMJK3LauFNW4rH0dfspWmXC@Ss6f7uSlVA8ukhSfV7sl2i5Pr7pJKT8Bd2VhzCBzoH8j2@upjov6sYw2YGaX62UeLZVHbT1C3lYAwrl3lTjxUlSGg@F8C1VpxuJQrwjX4p8tVufxLs96aZZCsfF6QLmr93c6lLM0dDqrW5jOGVuYnkwXSORp2JnOLmeVdpGPZprN8u1CNV@qudEtpgvl9u3Zp@tVJlBYWa24omLPMtPMuNKfpnpZYrzAt/qXPhGvlCzz88K7bScb/c5Y7G8ZZKMnhZHVGwUu8qIOdacR9uiHsmWhtUwJxfVRbWU0Cb1WimUKeWvRXWsM5nrtHPE2svkRIouB2I6fd4udrMDKn2dzY1CbdHg64pvXiRgmYLM/e4nbxUi6LpCwKiZKvXx93gMwd7m4uSdjSfIzhP49fadfSews8/2RgKi/X410ALl@F0t/IbwsVUIebYZxN9qwI8WT14@WwywznYC5IL38UBH5PsM4s6DUJeOM6/J@CAp7xFAnniSJyj4ORh5PflnxjH8gAa/gxLYRN6o8xDeeL9IG@EI3ucDb/3JPJxsPfL0sNvUYAKhyThFBH76XT/Duyp8CxnJI@B8teDd91ifOdnJD8QZmkJ2GnEFgi6S1d4VA2PaRWG1Jo5f781AkQ1ZnAdr73x9iqPZBBNLkv09kOI3/ZO75IP/iE@5kGBKnDIxpvq8Px6ow5mIZKSNegt@uXpCKBpBYSgr9K21LSgbS9Fko904nBMoSfbmPXR25ST7kuPNvMh@jHgTUDdC682sTj4gLwn48enYdfJKStHRxJFCa5OPyV3sIaWkmJPJnfJwovh8XtOXMn2sz4MjvmW9J9rU9kS8Mx/IW/v0EbpyXq3H32bAvr@qiGqqwg9Vt4HIh7G33zkhm5Y5HWjCadv9aSbwpqpvx4hYnrjJTkd8HYWfEnMvckqqA2cuNQE/ulvvSiCrIL/49M00Fjl5nY5r@M03eAuNE9t3YrsCnylt2pMl/pj6hvATPwLHr9MfH9ubwvAIy@0335A4yYq0aEGS4cHJJ04qr2pLO7NkgTw6dTndQnnmwc9Wvf6vgXSgeiCTj/hLWjqAWSAWe3fA0Rn5IoMAJBOqcLgsKOvnoHgfH@8J3uUEfXDSnB1/MDyWG7LvzqOJJLJLD1xOkQ1K9sBAXnvHCRJ7J@GX3ogrwZnbSvpmNJ1o5Plz0KLX5gj@TOijxkn6OmfQmOIveHsQi5khOUTjFsCBZ7zt24wzhe2mcdoCO76Rl69wfTC@GvnWCxDMc/jzw6Ab8csHGF9fJXm@sb5D60GmajlWWmTYeUk1vHZTA@PwNthuzX2MiB/cCUSRR6InW6kjSMV1fSN5AskTzhy@kTzEuKfGW8k6JOOv076RLEGy9U7k/nQV0q0n/W8AmNjLE8T10VQfTU6SPdaGHngrkGdLYXuQz@cwdi0CyGoYqz128yN7axT0wWodS9h2xAv6JxErCwCLtMfuPPh@Iy0kFe8S7rHkYqtMiyfoM/piYbZzJLD4kZQEaheX7z3awY@2CID@B6oUvU53Crdae13RHfkJwrAzwK0NzAqjH354jzJbEHflj31wpM9qIeyHu1VDi1sbPNbHMzftamVa2Zn257G3jtnWbo6PxKYeTqcMbVSI1bc2/VqUlD6UAYg/bEdjlycv@riJuTMe0PFae2z4aHWLL/Mx9Ep6sEcU6ZF@1NsE@a/nKoflHnJyMCL3NsoC7xPGnbxip7GGDuxCnwH0mpsv5IzfkRm7l/7Uyn5dbQ6APtKpCW9OLEXLg2l4ZhO4hzzOatdtnWAhO3QfW/H4U5/SLjLpDWTWfnqPgMA8BRrwyOaocWdMlJSg9U4q6HkmFPETF3ML5HnDJkdZfQ2f/v/irr2rjRzZ/53@FKK5CXbSNjaZuTuXV2KMAe8BzNomGQ5hEmM30BPb7XXbGN8Mn31u/aokdbcfwM7ec3bnbGjrUaoqSaVSSar6f5hcYJxesseIfpYWSWoBa@aKW7rBr93ZKTdDnkj6xcRdyqPmtQ9rwFHNjycedR9oldxUBWUdN22px@fl0F/jzI@4@1L6TpRZLitMp5uR@JIh@LiE0c8OsjQJG1cqxXGgwJLhmSWJnRAuXpTiq/VfTYq5dilze6kGBqy20vnAWQCaDFKUk7U8rXPtxqJTe1/8OjLKjRdrYQg6KqOCVPYtJynOsZ074MU7mWpdRzFHkjl4yQ4Nc2gwC26MbktqsKmXb39FNwuTwU@a07dh2MkYhUkrDAzBeOigQp64s7JqlaiXcfPUnFZ61a328mHW3S1KWdFJvK5QApRPPTaBxNtbnjZbmDYJ/SaIOCYu52M1oqbM6wNcVhTpozZn01HaqkCvFlYyEh8@ydhzpZbzvBKnxINbbvVxMRTdIVvrbRfptiNQZpc22rF/S@6DxwVWBvHhqb1b/khuXYKtIA@d2Ha6uQWZ3bLYbG@7aMYO@Mc/V1fWx9Fw/Tror/v9e1Kqr6fOqvL7EsltU41HN7lfcFG4VD/8pKUJ38vmS4g0TKin0Fq@708yKEOaM7yIullHfNLxpcWiA/fDfG@86993SOsXjy2DMHrgf6e0WSjkx4NRyDm6IfZdp/4I/oj9qRb4FZHeMWh0thlOXCaD9wWSOpW7krmiKEhFuFbOJkBcoiYLXPeL66L/gKi@T3p55UR5v9W@AxIYe3/Idoq6i0fyoxOZroevNbACj1fosyteJgZ8dxRNsHYSTfk3kY/fRXxICl9xxbjX@xSHLwQjpxuGAwxyXAVF/W1igDD@VaO5X6nX8zoqjtxYxy13uceMJ4LssI6jMthrvLitDneB0imvQCxgS3s7MXCWv8wjNKvZhKkwATuFV/BHKBTkivxrjgxbPivFmSX83En/isDLgvbqMSA9CryLq2US1XKmmimcYMWrZ7nRarfhCOLE74WEcdnvdglp4cWrmB34BEdM@@9s@9El2ryyyEt@bi4/l8rPS74gFZfKt@@GcaHNZCF39Udc7lG5cTFvrq0dRURXT9m7VD4cJvDeeqpslKdNWhAX3rVdKaPSZmynMnKJnN8W9L7krKTq2AFu8y8lX4/vDd3zFstU2Y/p9vHX0R3ksw8G/WRxZpTm@0H3g5gfbQ5LWAW3SlId/c3DTialNohocZIjMUGDmKft7k4M5V3RSByeM@7u9kc3r01SHzKzaEg4t7mJtWCOJLjEbb5jxj3wSkLtcPZKAgTDxEBTZubumspTXXmaAItSK6ZZx3gKTU9wIm12iu/gWvcf@MdM9jRyptzq4sxXgvmDEC8vLdIMYqG74i5mU1qajIZjXxI1UU@sInHb01mIi4XEaYgdaPsOksK26ct7kJtw3O@sWDmRFBRGUszx3eZoTscFimb4LutCZD46f66/dQ5bPdIKu/6DKkGnbrEnfif12GbkR6OI5oBPBA5VNB4MuoH266Ym/JxDxwDa@BmPEWKICaUh71TxQFTKe/jSj2OoUl7VAHmCd4ZxRjS@RUhsWIIR3ZlE601AIEd5p9SfsmdidoO2IU9efDWGH1cI4C5t@xJISM/J7GHLA7S0vGMeFgmpNzK/@yNSgYjwkH0ewtXqpuP8Yxy0v5cP1Uah8Ldi4X0xwTJjqi7k3/@kqgkVyWRsFIqFws/FnxynHA6m8rQx084C1k85APTUMRb6TzQ2/XtEX3ZKtGJwwYhU/8gf3vudvOPU/Q7bgK/HzBEM5XHkixdl9vOKFNKt4O@e1N1e5Cnadt1BvOAv1mfxXdtmxxqegzdEA3/YC0by0ii8DzpgoHk3dRN2u@GEDdF4siT8QKWePyKmvM2qNErsl1bjwroLu4slbiCmAzvwuw7v2Y@0ZgPpqQHc7/MDIAdOFAEh2ZhEmE9gQu21u62gh@G0AAF4WYo5YBAg0jrjtv8kDg4j8S/ioDRhnbA9hmfelumZdZJ@Ic8Vmu7@MCDpGzOYe4WrJXCnDm4eVRuqUTtofi7VK4q@z@q1T9X9yr7au1DNo4oq184uOO6XOqodk3RpqNLpPqWeNuvVvfNmjRLcUoNqupzhlE4vVOXXs3ql0VC1uqqenB1XCRqBr5dOm9VKw1PV0/LxOS3Wh54iCOq01lTH1ZNqk4o1ax63aqo5cT1VO1AnlXr5iH6W9qrH1eYFt3hQbZ6isQNqraTOSvVmtXx@XKqrs/P6Wa1RUSDM2a82ysel6kllP0/tU5uq8qly2lSNo9Lx8Qyhtc@nlTqQT1G5VyEsS3vHFW6J6dyv1ivlJgiKv8rEPELw2FONs0q5io/KrxUip1S/8DTQRuUf51SIMtV@6aR0SMQ5mWe4Qv1SPq9XToA0caJxvtdoVpvnzYo6rNX2mdeNSv1TtVxpbCnnuNZghp03Kp5CKE9ummAQtyifvvfOG1XmW/W0SWvG@VmzWjvNUid/JsYQliWqus8Mrp0KtcSkWv0CUMEH7gBPfT6qUHodPGVulcCFBnGt3EwWowaJic0kmeq0cnhcPayclivIrgHM52qjkqUOqzZQgGCi3c8lavScqUY/EV7ySYPVMSPX4@5U1QNV2v9UBea6NI2ARlWPFmZb@UjznObyurPwyO3JA7z5Uz5tCnnaSXy5tl8hjU8iw7hx@jktOr@kD@9SebTQ2Ez6qU9Bea362vGvx7dfg/5NiK25rSYn2L3o1kMopSwCqX5xnggVrQ/KucLq6tevn0pfaZ/b@Po1672kZgqN52poL6xPlcpqGrthq8Pb/JRtKcmo3Tfa17snjpeTtpY31viQVevrHV9Xw@NFADZmIh2UgIB1IBn5VWOrrxJN8hFz2lbEETNmjUXmeDOM6J/@H/EPWRsSCSSc5d7C@jr2sIwGIp8oiz81wkFBdGQQvgcQ3HCT@cj3v99mCsnmsOXXBqqsqcNlR7QNvM1kn6l@7d/OVM/N1mdk8daUlRXjDt64acfADPmXZpnS/ZIfMmUZMe3xn6zBhhsipTArTfFDVn37JPNGqsO/qNgKs1vWlTiHAzkp/Vr9jM1cYeOnrZn0I5sucwuvzhHbhta7S653xX@OrqQATbAA2y9iSTCVI9X19UQd0spYn7SF4av@DoUmQYfWVCzVdz4v6/CQL@6Ck/VpMR4GD0nsSQwf1ksne@cHByQ5ge1Pv/z8t//ecrTH/eHoV0/@XqAdBMdk7pIWPQlITeOsxCwpk95zMBcsJxHdB72Hggg0aTqNE1uk0lrPmaIjSHwNMQOB3AgRBvoIsuEiSMDQVXif7684ZrwunJl6AGRSpGZBTa/1wBp@i1QlHgNt8ZLZnXKvPeAfwLbT30xxS5AeQHqI@b3BaEojlzYXLPfcA@NwgPc2/KwYRfKuGceDlrmDJIyBzGQvDHiDz7/02E70Ium16GjMV@52rklIrMxiYYK0cMglauIsjMwMlsSAUn7V440@L3RwIGQh1ENp1CA2HtiaORO8R2zOemJoyFe7O9RFb97YlrYVDKlZjZTY/9OhY5KzgVGRCw1qBrC5eWT5bHPYCP1xLat@yEiFV2/A2dIjVv@mkbuIHA1ly7hE179NBBklsOKAMpw0sW04psiFKWLZmWLTv8UPhv8f5MkC@Nu04SToMbdYDgf9sf9CTjJU4RXtXpkpwcTcGEtcU4u5mUy6iME8JjvmzhKmr@E9yMESsUD3ztQkXEhIscwCBmCQw66RnL9w4MuT@K5FO6ePPHdfyUn/sN/uDTImIJdZKubgXnmsc3nmihx@ZOUIv6ASzR0jvspH9vPIMgMbLpJi11P1OnIFxrsiyxwQvf6WjR52lvPQBBuKZobHw6mgp5aZ/A/6hlG8ynRM7iOposuDfdnjEMQUSgl8cwJiBAjffUoSrNlGbe4C0YV0w9MLW/mVXsUR2ZJEIK/LqsnuOaLWDe@ZsRRpXxpw2oEmAed1R8dsuvZHEywXXYHOPkRiaCrzmt2YoBFti7RqhBG@2TxxnRfZicWezZQYrxb78/73PmIs@2LiMiXyqQhQSReseXXS4mBQ3ZfR7caNvwNbd9PtV/vsV6Ut55UwzfHOnVrBTv91FHOENM4JtEtah2IutdrfkeiaMRpMcsED/eG2cppyE9OI9gwcsW6R0v@4dEOAsTJzB1a5X/rWiLQpC9nOa6O@4Evmrv26wJe2M@8QUYQcpeDCrFaDgDL0JlzSnJ9tjF/KrQ4un26S5jSZ5K9b416rf9PqBd0p3zr9Pbzrr0f9cTTID6aO67ppayAcgcNFCuE@8tXnoN8JJ5Hao@kAQ1Lj9Lxxljb8JSxfZbF8KfV3akPtccvOHPgb@EyKwpsRdY2/paY6SPkwNvewnVBbWtisNUUCHFMNeQBRuz2rGR@enqtDv@8PSR884zuX6jho@30SH6RM8S3M6E4kDYofoPWGbl0dQHdhy86W8gM26ljbnqMb0NA8DK0MTUVCeKjDKsI2P6WhnrAJ5ucJjunqGKPSXTjQ3oBgNIWyKSbOm3HXcxC78XO1eYTNuGzM2TZDy5qx9cGWKKpTT4y1RMyw1R9NiSnOrPGG0H7OdpNX7AyIIDrL2cmbuh5itHdg9utGRCoizGspwCsITVU/uEewODbDvaSP@J6tNpvFfNvS/hU9CV9nREeq95y49zzEDM176uf/UU0fY1eddVtt2mGpxhjV378nPXAvjEYoelJSqrBRLBZzxfcw0Z43SnmeCPi/iSDmONWTs1q9SYzULvLNwLBrJpjPQbvkNhaxI4fQXUT9NwhkU54k5sY3Zh5UcOPH192SEwt306W@b7dg7iUKo7Q6zCZZmOTDIQcOgzcoGkKp6UitwukBQvSxkERLCegehy7TwcdkabF4sjc/rvANuHVpXHVxHvqNK3MaCQD/gdOo1pB3Bh3t9p76pOf3LPbByKzuLSngzMY8swwTWyoNjjVvDVoScS@bhNPxcUciQvSAXnTfHpJsad3TkMMVFuMSi8YMy6aspaZ1HXQDmgOEV/suxIIj4sp0BJsgkhHRHO5xG2sHCxLjsiBaAc2uTtizRQUrx7HO4HT6IJq2Q7V6S9ts7LSige93OFLCeCChAJCfp1nepZVD3MRtxjECnNUC35sckrBBSBaSfeMufMfC19@19LljqKFRZdwLNu@wrRdARFFjxJMUEdsyC3bYnsI5b5a7vUUDAnWzYMQSR38EYuDhUIqwov7mAcFfPFw8uKPqcn/P@gFERQ5GFA3SGYAlp7p@OsOAB@36c66ADNIdi8CMi0GDjPjJku@UDSz9A/Ti3imcpmWERiJumrXMPAgQQlNsA6G6DfEvCucNx@SM0OczwjnHhQ9wyUvwZksW50tSKRtAJFFyYwHM3EKY7xfDzGmY@rCy2r9nh22oxcNCqBBv0CHJRzAiJv8wNKKX3cp1QzlgstTfdsNrxG0iSUGt4c/Uizs2mcw7sBSjk7niRDAdb2rbkKRR12@bjO6itml@@Ltq21gsdr/0paN0xo7MJfZZpnjt4unEn/hHzyj@dFPBq6B1zESvAnqSSrIbYF0NUqe4myqembiJkyyvW05X6aWqFGeqaOTSVa5TVTac2FPpTO@iBkQ//qYpM3oJ30riHlA7toMKTq/1ILubAjugYzMNQkamPOJtXOkBgoKXbWV92qH4lRO7aE4d20sb5idfweMb3@5/uRzyqpCOd/Bgru6xGOBSqfwpuwHvZzRBWc0G/mHdP2cNMpquba7ST0gqS7BkOCmyh3irlUm2kt1Uq4OWnBqiVISFLdn0JfMAp/Qu/fdWZXQDuSSyUghudbUoJMaz6@VL2spKtxg5WHDilZl/JQQc9aAj8puvjMkykMmk5pWR3BamfM7JbgKFdAHHLTni/zMivU5SsaIkREMDCh/CmGolz3@g7RmfMTMIXn@sxVonik9jKz008pdxy1dm1UhTsbT07FKyqExiVbFceKqwYbbl09LCy1cbZh1sCJB3UjzBumMYiTXrzBK8FgnLWEsJRuzsNGwHIqHSbEsIXanrLRDA6S43yHkzVDkJV@aawtllxEmtnKlBkkn8Qph29VoC2QmgrJOqBf4v63Bcd0xO7KXlilJOd/uyEWFhmX5/aljYwqbfnxoWUjjR7U8PCxPL0LKW68@Oi1RPCAtwKVHvGNimlJRBJuMhWephphQjNL1K@jL3u5kF2CakqrZ1OnOqkmWRDl2SboP/PEjHrGpHo6nhSMy7tL1xFVNLa1z7u9@xHpk19XaLtOumlwTpzdlABCDatMB9dJVFyGxbgSS2GMH0nrkndzfZo/2abFh4D4qoXbd36de9KbBmVSlk5xVK470/Rn57IfK5@SgK8RZrcz4@vL1dprHGhadw2EFp11lw4us8g9W7BFZp6hI9lGbxEki5F0HKvQDSegKSntjvab3kz9Uh4tT5z4H48mUeBv/5jTZSGgZJ2k4AIzb2wZPW9DmYK6RsrfKdupbcKrMVYj35ORgfZmFwXNA7exqnE@9asLr9rz8MZ6NyLOVseqwswMhitTqPlge0WGrzfleXM6oS723z36/vArsTWH2@p8WPsa6Mq8R39hBoNe1V3wKL539xCf@8RLem54MgnjLDkLbs/IvTIQ9GiIVJnorZCglBlt6H6ow0I57OnRV@vFud9X6MgKdLq2WfpeSjGHwSRqcikSYSKzXizBYuFk5mtTLybdH27Nn2Vxe2PwgHpOPcLESAy/dgxxej1IxIj1XTma31i9ayhevZPF1JvW0mNsnLJ/mbOdI3iHQ8TKdJ3fcnevV/CrKmxfTAX9DkL80YWYLk64VI4qC9pY1bqj/uXftD5yVTXWrk8Uf2SMtHruOsrqpSm7bM2jM@rGJtDt/n6yahBmMgRGo8wHlNJJc7MblhI/NlAM@W7YSTPpfOu2iCbbQ9v9XXrvL1gnk7xPmFLeshfCced3ELQb9NjI78hPnzm8Sk7vg6BzeSn2Dr1uK@x6hGmxoLL25JoyW6Zmaa3tNK6hIFx2o1XGpzVlExYweHoW9FM9f6Einm2cUmsJdoT08pRDSIlzWpN7wzoJ8eo5vLmTkeWFbarnkBKxepW9bK/QJ1a/pSdes/wMnZDnUS31p70Avs5rNCbXaT7/y5vm4DM/YWuG751Dw4SDk8uZ6aXUHPH/5cKBTgBOe6FfGpRcobDk6Jg3A9XXodNvH1weTvw0/X66iKQwtEJtg0h5l@FHZJ1ET5cHgr0SiAAxVFaRxNYJzgaGJM600i3APsOX28yvk9kpLigaej@BpnYC@3f2ry4GOQYJ6/qb6BQND3Td2M@2JEn7Rky6ChmPtmVBtq6L1rrskRe5BwA4869koaA@N9s361gIOPnd0fzis@A5fnghwuPvsjfoboHvndbuipz@Gw21lx5XVousLBQbJCQYrgKqFMnojDF3vKvw@6iRDOKALcwq6f74a3DA4n4PrZIr9lGvoDnKRlsI7V/dvKwyDjXv7m0sAkkt@BzHfKvcLznluXliiXj9CfBysBMwjtF5XutQaZNvNptjCtgfotVfxFGL0veqoht4NhTykTybjMkUkVyYpfGOHZ86XB1MXo5n8Pg36GSEe2g@dy/PSbu5cpWVLcMtf98lC8AQ8LAkPjhBA9L6vxuAWnU3/9f7Buw3KAx41s47VPYhP@xpJ0GGM8Zpa6H93c0PQSS/yucTVmwLGozBX5lgJYozt26P8TsQoyazfRmgRYwVWbxrTfTiFyuXHlqbXx6OaXNYLwb9HomBmopx/x0/k/)

<sup>Languages that are not in the driver: 
7 [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4), 
26 [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122),
60 [Moorhens](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/tree/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24),
83 [Objeck](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/),
90 [RunR](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0),
94 [Emotinomicon](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html),
96 [EmojiCoder](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/),
97 [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183),
104 [Paintfuck](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9) (origin at top-left),
108/110 [Ruby 1.8.7/1.9.3](https://rvm.io/),
119 [ImageFuck](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck),
121 [Braincopter](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip),
123 [Mycelium](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium),
127 [Deltaplex](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip),
129 [Brainloller](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip),
131 [Extended Brainloller](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk),
136 [Wierd](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)),
140 [Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus),
141 [Floater](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater),
142 [BitChanger](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl),
145 [MiLambda](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php),
146 [Curry](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~pakcs/download.html)</sup>

### Explanation

VTFF is a language that is meant to only accept vertical tab(VT) and formfeed(FF), but due to the author likely getting decimal and hexadecimal character codes mixed up actually only accepts device control 1(DC1) and device control 2(DC2).

VTFF works by by counting the length of each run of DC1 characters seperated by DC2 characters. A character is associated each each of these runs of DC1 by adding 31 to the length of it and interpreting as Unicode. These characters are interpreted as a string that is then ran through eval() in JavaScript.

This program was generated by running `148` through the generator on the interpreter website:

```
␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␒␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␒␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑␑
```

where actual DC1 and DC2 are used instead of the representation characters.

This code was placed after the formfeed that is part of the Trefunge.

The test driver has been updated to pretty print the DC1 and DC2 characters.

**Update**: interpreter is changed to accept VT and FF and added to the test driver.

Comment: Wrong number (also affects the VIP score)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen fixed now

Answer (score 5):

## 165. [Ursala](https://github.com/gueststar/Ursala), 8238 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
# 36!@ `  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] TaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbLzLzLzTcTcTcxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             x
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#x}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx4O6O@x0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x********>********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss      <e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf  
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-} 
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>main=putStr"128"--}
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78" \++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#}pS9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8     \      @,,1'1'<>   @125iRE                               _
# |o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>27.say#]# print(47)#]#echo 21#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwv>++++
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>}[<<}< <<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  eeeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zb1rcyNJkiD2ufL0D/QlmGAXMgkg8eAbIFiF4qOL3VVFLsmqmh4QxUokEkQWgUx0JkACxWLb7kk2t48z6W527mxuVrc9szqZ1kz3Ye0kmd3ZrpnMdF/P9kf0flyTaf7ByN0jIh94kKyZXTuBBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeEU0z6PzmNyn8sCOvO77oegM2sIMBa/nOle0b7NmYPTWdYLW0rCgYq@ZfDHu2OwjKSooVGXNcy2nBOxt4l7brfLR98C8x1ve9C9/ssUHHHDA7sMy@HTBvOOgPB8xrz062zNhez/vg5DBlz3EvINrA9vu@PaDwFcZeu12z12yZEyGrExn2fQgP2K7d/dT7NGCW1@uZbiuAmGuMvfT8wMb4lh0EHiZfZ2y0Z1sTQDcgquk73ovaqy8ngjYZ@xJQNPtde8TMZjDwTWvgeC7SpMBOXr0@OZpIUSyyN6f7@5O@JfZ1znPZ/tC6nAxaZq/9wOyaCfhUB0e@1xpaSJ9Bx4ZkSNO207UDxYKyb7O@qEkDHSzFfNts8WhK2/MZJmG9yy5zmNXvs2bX7BgW6zoQd7@wwWysAvYRwrudgI36PRY4PYASeD07jmPAXNtusaBvW07bsQgDZo8GthsApoHBHCjTtdPtspbdhQQRWlYWgLFhEPPiSBhKy1MYfKz@RCHCt0Ub4ri2JITdhxpCQnhYoUAVSY9r3@z3AUmg5AkgPnB6wH/OIB0w2wwc5HBIEthui2jYD3nfY6YbLyW7cqAGAN@hT7AD28eKMAgu69i@DSDNkPu0a98ZAAmQxDV2ZJs@O/VtW0@2g0SWkJmHOQywIAZV4dZWeu9wPw1VyVMYZn@gpPzl09/7SjGZUWWL5xX4VlW1ouy92mU3i2fo5mwP1d33NVNn1e9YkD87s@E7KjbzF/6tAlAVoEqX5b3@IG/m@oBgbgAI5k10oit3VTL63VjGbGuiLmIMxmO1oDbYgcveZKlk1tD3sWlHRDUvodBdz70AekJh/aGL9HDZWgGqwPKgZWaZfQVUg6ZAdeRdE4VPOw5UWoBVEmsEXEARQUFEAe8Jisp8A687pHiQMhggAwJVIClCPGizN6xtOl1MAuEIimPt28GwO8A0Q7eFNQ8CyG4ZTKJheS2M1POuIDsTgJIHtKderBUSUhAZKsKjomLQD//iz1oXFwCnZlme3xLs@oa1PItEqUnIgnxiyLCea3YJLYiXxdx5csjgyuw6LXOA2btjkQUhQblee8Nui3mQoX/tQNPqmFfQHNtt2xrYnMm59M2ynnnJZYfDORcK3jObULGUAeVNxc6xpztQS5atpIhncr3hoL3Bcv09lg7y77QnZe3JwpkNyOmGvrSYz19UgOGMJfKCt/RdnPOmlpCawcAMPKel9MeDjueWWM5iqlX1@rarpRMw0tm030zrBso0Ta84VctoO25LS28BL25Dxmm9YlWtulNuVCaSx7MEMNcIBpurrVm6qoDIoUZxle@Zjmv0x@xNTrhiYV5wjiTHYCPmjYSZ9LviHinqfZAvPWQQkENG0LXtvlYwijqKCYw3s9wYMKukEzBEgctOI5NOpTPxohMEKGmioNhYTx0PxVa338GOB4jiBn0Q3z7yrmUC9wQoxQegAmRZk/iaRD9IFpKJ13bat1kTBKnkI2qSvMlh@hwKSgEhakIyXrJF261YgwZhAG16EExJ5a53DRkTbtiHgQhxMXPzAqoIEvMC1XiBeI7kkyzapQuCBaE1bbaRazrQGLDZgWwXvB8rI0RfLvE4AI03lpgM6pljgGLxPjFqOMxpQ5vqgZjwx8yyUfaAELJ5x4KZDKkdBqD8oBpUyJVWV5NtbaqpDfx8LfdjENYf83e2KCx8LaEqQA/Utq9Z13QvhuYF6l8uJDEty@4PhMCCkgQDEEmT/Q555kQnagQdZfHpZN7UmYjuNZYHCntee6JLNFHKCA0s1wWhykyhQ7KW44N46o4nc4cIVxOZq@8xSgKB9@ocFKQmAExmj2xrOADpBox83XGsDvAuYudy@cg7o8nswSueO0j4XDvMGpEpbj8uKUY@9EI05oLIYY1Ow4FOFkFtJzyo8uMed0M2g94MwF6IInQIMV8jbxrAe/fA7HmuNwMoEDIEi1GSIbweQCM7QW0QOjCpflFjDVXEsIqgzkB6QMsH/usMBv2gDP2FM@gMmwZwSv7UHx8MDl1klvzAHzsDj7ubXa8J4jmA9pmXOeStYdMZTRSI/MI6/BAoV6CItQNWhR782yFwnZZuByA4yX8HI8eCVBLgBIL/qhCRIhlAKK0dkEjeB6FyMnYtTTWoKRnQ6NQsU7Hhqjo4MFVIlx2vh1KIvSUFATW@Zz5IrjZIKyH7SfSbM7u8sA8g/S6dNj54jqvdpBcWFtLl9DZI@IWFJ@DaQtcTdGXA9YRcOXJhPANdlCJLLgytUwr0a6Rv6xLySG9gtY2wd/ro9DWzXi4vN7JmvSieJXzqIOpAskHsHD4ATlqvVtGp6@r2NRTUaLaTpd9B6Xxi@U5fEOEr88rk74IKy0QGp9f3fFRkK9jZ3k2TXtWH3hCUV6uj@emzeuGscXZz1sqc3aazmFqvmNUmFAry03rGhe8NodvU6yvlXLGh6/Vl6Cyb1XQhvaRpG7kuZGTq@hcbesbk1NbSNkht7ewsDUQV9KlbHZ/gjbIlXQ9JBXhgBw26oZY2bjYg/6be0DNpSKunszDUqKbTQBkLiRBQoZEziUD7wIA7Jy8SQ8DeJYhHZgVd1ClyPlcr4DW/xD1b9AhVpzI7oJ7Vhf4SUIDushUOcVzPzblDUoRJS/XiGdFgDGOQH3YeKBidRBwE3HZGoOlDwx1LjQY7YFRqdmC453Vt4y3pGCoDzmfYXo2Zas0R7xcMK4gqERQYcPa7pgUtMwnuTGVnABAYNZ@fHaJXpgBP6jw0PLmvjNAzWKaL9Gs5pH4PnaCD5AUVCccEfhuoiro3dO42Ue2AWdBpXwCl7ZEz4Mo4MMIJJnluBpqO6l@Nq0@otWGXj0jJoTv1x54FAxcbun4M5aNAtudeOb7nIpGNPQANHFvBOpgAPou8wEa12kFpdz59ZwEHik15F2O0jUOdJK4VWCzvel3vwmNLEAFZ0zA4Yx@4FqAAStsAxokscD4SgWoXHoxgkjxoY38doJJXXFsO1WgTY@YpvvEBhAWbXegowpwynxz8eA9EfHG1UAD85VuBPmEhY1Amy4ieFosiiGYLTf@0M7QV2@p4TD2DDrK0zfIt@yqPzU2FnqgDml4OtCnbJ10iTCamppSBNwSlpGV3nZ4zOKA5mq6LPW/Uq8jQHWCvCMCRYw8UoS5HnTFO10SC0r3g8fdGKE8DxaYne3W4u3d@VDt9XlXzw8DPd50m1F/LPu@B3tS1A5WxFDu2IbVI8PGye@x5gypVCc4MTX9SGEnGf7F7/uLg2XHt@BueDaULnN6wa2JmPP4JvUs2iU0rtX2vF@qIgaDt4jJS005MD@LASYSuYOhQTA7G/NfQv4cTfoalXFgWy3n8NfQUEdcxIk4CGla/r1xkMhiTJgVDTxFzg0DixKDhN6XnJnqGU4IxNTwOblb4/EQC8k2xcIvAA3cY9GMluykWyf9q0G5jPxJ6l8j7MgdgQIEMvZfJm08pJrKSZJkKmhmZ19cpCK8XHgiqF05A87nxClTCHvFMUWW3nui91SikFA2zWe5q9vyAGgdEvAS1f@mhNhm5zmEsvIpQQhC9y@50yjbIdPpJRJ1CajqE83Cv2aafGRHKYsgJDRInQJEqX@H0GY56Pehh7WuKRsozAQNqOa6ZP6YHqtGz8EkOCBLINO32EDqfPGg36L4nWm5zg2K2m01nXlSgC6IunzOi@cPmLLKBMt@ZGjOyBOEHQ3/QtVvi@V9@vwUVMF09HXNMHW7oOAe6EW@059aWSIov9DO7ZinOh2HXMYkM5LoPpGXidJ3ZDR2zQaPsZLlcx/R72K@JygXmxB9om3fwGcfct7vDli2fszMhEidHpjy16/SoRPBExYwU7TnJJ8bVPD2pNl3PbBEUroA4dlTbvF7sEe@KY502iL8H4CmHvyyad4Zx3mDIf3Gq@b56dfr4nU2VcpLJCqtms2jnvcBsOvYdfOCbl8OWl@tfXlChEbW1edzOGxGO1nLtrnnJnefonE0AXkTfubiAUap4zot23QEFI@iDipK/pscdrCI7AEa9tHkXTL/Lf@dFkatvoWM@nZwu/XwOQxKLWNBqkLS4CJSLkcmZIGzXbI5xnNX5fM7CDKlnBcFTtTKZwjJ2Y@GkYbTc1O/PT499H6Xf3Jydmq9MEQDLa7dt@77WDD2S0zO7uVIr5pwrnOUsQOSaEZU035zVNQNgkoEgs30F1UI/dzEudjIWskvkuoNtI3Tk3PC86cUoTd@xvK4T9HlLEi/zpOTkxEwEBtcf6SdKim/T9G2Beo8deC50zW7onjXAKb45fPQAwcVn13D@MsYYhjePdpZ3jd@5qkPHu7L57@zO7ONMrB4ggnJd4gzHmpG8Zd3HrrhYRD@zqXg5E6uB1Z3pX2YvPc/v2G7ASkZBTkfgDL3Z7fLpvtODw/k8HThdL4CRAf7eRQsYAQQB/53NzXGyOaabo0mXuHt2MoFUnxlijDqnMs3uhddd27jIm/Azt8aHfhslu3g@VKKFEqlYvFcihYqP5xbFc64ov4T/@5iBJnZ8nMGNOe/oR2eJLzHzN7@AMDzAZZnZhdsvbFBKI8@HafMqwLc61@ZYPn@L3mIedWVv0R@T2gx6HSbY3ADHwOeq9G@T28rdubUeJpOmwK7fV4hY5V52bZDQ9DtVpaxUKH5mimKh8HAJ1e4O7aE9U2IcNj/YaP1yh6x4OFIFUYxFMWWRB@LhhEUY66MYFD4Ia@y/8e1OAWN2HWjk92ovM@VdH3TtPo6jj8BxhI7phBfusJ@o3Bjtjofu8d2U6/Rly/ZaCSQx5HMl0sb9OlJCHQ9s@s5T3fd6Hgx9vR7oDO4D6l8ApTkg/psATD4R5A8Ozpf5d8Its3CpB/RV0D@gVp3LIIeTbg8TPKV5Y3aKvLkJozLXHozxdx61ZwnSpud1P6d2QJ62HFTLQNlEm677amlK1xGrfiyanQhwpqPZnjcvwfsaMYAE6uFgeW5FH0GRBtQ5PKSWpyb57ui1YlN@940jocemyZ/At6R7Hr7H2LiLxoaxfifCXB31mnbX5I/R2spd8DaN5YeoRH2p59KsL84U87nhaKUiNSGC@mMgltPKBVbH7tn0eoeSb7Y@DAP5mBtp5OF3RrCRp2nROen6DrR5F38T89AxrWjguXaQH5j@hY3Dky4uDwjfeXJWzrbOJO5Bz7yw9@9lrmj2AU1CaPkt5pw9D1Hmq7QWJLtHkvCRn@de2uNAPmfrx2ML6nPYuxParHZu4STnvQ3byM@cZL5H7XM7Xsft2B2fGkf4Nq95AEcOuOnrXYUA/DtmcIk2MCSTomFdJ4hTt@t1uw@hLspELiE9b/b86x4an7Yg6WfBHZtNCBCPe6fqoOsmIlEfPq/tdOwh9FCBN/D6do7e5kXt4qQO/509pXxwmA7YW8f2W3z9D2f4zIHT7Nrs2gEUPgTxdbTZE0bNrmeimdUdSjxQRj4fMgVlef59vcKF6Q36fXqc97vDgH5oJjfXnj1FWWb7hOhDeMEZ8JVXzrH2hde0Os59lde0zYHrXOZF6xevs7k8KYup4A7L7aK30XWAVP7YQB6oxsNP8HEwu907L4Th@p36yM7Q98f3y4bkqmI4q8rXAtAxb/5FrBbNCKaeH80L5DL6HQsSYnFpLkORLo16c84ugHJSnDsblDCFECToLi8P7qGS5VmX96oTc@cnxUIkkspyYsul4D85iXE3Gs@FeIPBofZ8eBHo98Ufo6q16/S4ibzZjYyA7klZu@CcgwtJQde7jk00g0gwXfGYyXmlF/e3J1oNWb1zYaTMii/Oa4cH9wOzuk4/4L8s1y7NVCGmFxunYvGVxmOyFQ@tCYOsMHIHP8cXJs1BuG8gRfYGZFsobc1YCi0eh1jlA883GMXTNDOT0XWFJ8LJswsXoslYZLmN1pzcKDxgXScYUFynzep1tngzKhfKxVtWZWpZZY0Gh0p2hXujPplcH/Ok9UWzUV1M53LpxfSZW2aFNEW1u4E9O6qZiNd26MHxjIrOXJNbk6BblrTCrVSDDlmCg3hsgZh9Dco5NTXP57aW3KD3FFfh/vNftoSBPKhiAes5UCdACNzU4fXsjnf9hOcrcq/1@yYa2COM6w7KcMw9t1NjwTXKY24X712z1/unG8LKVmw9gZcjFBwxLHil4rgATWwGvNI4Ni3P5jwmMg5TyUJZXnfYc6EDbA06gcFOHLKeGfqR1QC4MJo78FELaGXZAWvZuNZBRlGk@HY975LMExGT//yX3LaYTKOEyYrMnvYWxHJEC6giGfRaljcErCWQj7bviSgaEhk4e4jDSmghNvfX0WCIjJ6BE3PS5Bez4Wa/O7UTlttjadwbg4aEFaetLdaOv3xTLzSq37Fe3v4vv5/XbwTd1C9y62uBmmUySuUW@SoevArBUWiaqYsjVRQLd2HQpoOQqcT2LA3dVF3ShLdHGziI7@xrMuElwxMXGy7ujABxFoDqNdAJNG801UVtyAcwuZMBW8UNRDAmMMHFt3yQQRSao2KSxRH7xDrIKzkLjXTgjROkixbQveozuYa9HLc0yO/azSEtr12VjNJylYqzeF7d2iaXb7c83JFQf3c2KhVyZ6P1vUY@kMQ5Oxt9USj9CKjngW61@DiPDWjv1e7NorFd@PQpMMdMVW/TFW5AAa188ebo4Gjv5LR2@voEqHnLC5va9/yeGUkK5AWyOep4XdrqAWTxHTu4X3qEEiR8g@iaxhZNtoW7ynRdiRvcUFRBajWnLnJnGAUGGfHU9ySflT6wY@HTEYRkajtMSFF2RIwkeCYdxCVoVvIW1gs2d1AFQ4qgecoMUUg0UlkVqJQDKj2QRmy6lLwGn5AHVOP9hLobxiwQQKsoxnQEJFKYF5aXh/PCzSz87T9AifvQr/2uJSYYd5YYY9xVYogYJaMU@7WDF6@P95KJgJ2ifX0wkPNxi2eb2hbfIcS5yxObUaRkojFQIIzOQ9kasCsnoDES8lsbe4YuCBdsjrTKHqB04SaqrNYNQJK3WiCamuMBSjYQ6QbZTXHjqZzL1BQQywg72ixTFYwbVKc3JYDkurZAir3niRcpHkEOlBm7qM7s/A//4s/4zqmzAbj/SLhHhWfw9ifirQ3ufy5DikV4@5fhWwnefsrf3uWRlNPbRHhpQiIiAd8cHLGAhnFIop45ipUe@zbsOx0XBhJOD2h9RaTD6LxYEWUiOFr9DVAeqgvIjkIa5TLlZ/sNDY38y/k8qiI492aQbY894oM4svn/doh73qArya@trq0UYRRj564kQLLbvUBjEg5Q18vAlcqV06@@b1psa2uLqYFldu3qWoWTPL9ovltW34eILkJchWstdQZpIEmUAsK2RTJt0cwUdUyKjTNdTLNGBRQSXoPQp2nkgCg6ervS9BM6TU@QCtjDtUcDEvxjqY2BKuSS5aHNdz5KQDkAxGHjzqxJLo/MQ9CaLsb3Rrwa1LcY7QSjldVZTFZ/x84GZ25D7NBjwDC/nMFyLrj/eMa2vZB7atP7xbTJ3V5YGvb0xPXQjGgfsGVaKV9azhfX9FibUgUowBdb0CcACW0G2qBlOx@8flDb2Tv46vDoZGq/E8VMT0ZLs/T2VuYsZ2TrjdCRnuB6SdRn@/mTl8/2JSnjWEWz8BgjmoqfRHNWbpOYzsn9LbfLmc6bAqYyKhYeCpiGkrl9Wq2ahh6F5mMRd7jdwFSumn5zW29sbZ@5qansP83aC5oylpC5wHUW0E7QNJshcw6ktdEpbvoPDGmcWlKjnc6hOSp/j7zn71gKjxCIti1JuyaFLLJDg2zFmGPxBGU38jwr2rPDEZP4gqyRqBYR1ShDS5laSYljw0RZpk87EIbHIZEO@UCWtmSaLoxhfMfisQMS0Hy4S/sHYcBzMIjGSDDuwukDGgqOadgDoiKcwGg5NLo2fWk3HIac2D0ndyrxQcERbUMS@286ULau06yY1fqIhUa9d@3GMYJ@1xlouDVoZOBwEkqj6ViA4hburRnpW5sNsY2Jyd1GGdqwdDQEeh15fRYN4Xdt6TqGURzbHQJwYAObfTXsQbw2PY5t7CVs9srLQWKgY1oiUcctOqIMRq@1CrkbHXvUci6gp9H0LIikL4rFaKuTiXt13DTIYU6qL9G8JE6Yz9qeFaOYWTcNx23ZIw13FZQbSB3wT1@/vUrr6hQP0B4xsWWqNblZTAoLcyBabbTRakIgbG6GgiDZdjY3jU6goNE1jEAgx5OB/wKc0Idq7Z7ZZ9qQdtsFzGD0qp1pbjYY@DrLbWN/ds1clsnQ2AUeFGAwStkml9PFOVwNN6lr@SrUM/oGbgsfH50@qxcNowFuykRnizj7sAPqBo7bdQVUU0hSJrDQAcNfGTG6hlEaYsSfi5StQvtlINbMYGrIFx1qgEALKjXbfhxtz4i1QE7Vzc2yqI2kONxkwBZbMyQGgJ0h5qRuCvQVZrNANRRiEGsHBqUOCJSnX9uuC@1VA57pQetk5hCYzNez8rSVbLT5nnJIcRSfCztcQDS5KX8vfdP1QJ9ZzFdoBFy5hX7//Rl2/G3R9Y/z/23eyFdutMVudZwHZUzf1hY71WJmeSmTWXSXtEUX1ZHHj3HgfLsI2s65oRrqCCLlFrt6BfgZtKPqoltZNLe0xVa1tEQp4DWT0W8gwXdB3rhZNG/zi49Bm8iCj89bp7YY0D65gmEUbwE/bCGL@SzwzA3uF6MzVDD7RSeTQRyMxXNE4Lv82UmG@pWzkzyN0StCyc1f9KQYSeoqYU1Mnf3CCSi8y6FEX0WJLtZaz2Xk@Jb8GWF3atdfo2UKo1l0Owji/JUMebhgEQINhZMQMhrfqAgEHGlARHzNmroOwuQ3v0kV12DU92RtWfMyT1YLlUx6tVhJp1jqqZpfUn315mw3d8XsXLreNleNbxtHl0dHP9LPNLbJ0qmdQ7W4or5jm6WlvJLKLxU@refz79@/B3WY1beNbaOh13PpRl3jA7p1tr2@vpRd21jKPk2fRyPIdaZrpZIOlXbGVtnZumkuZVZKT90KhGziZ5kVwYm/G/AtstVVtoefv/0//vbnf/sz@vs5ff/acZx@0GrB1@uwS/YRPpdthv/k/tiKuU10N9sfNRhngPpZpaZRPEqnV5fTJ@9wR@yTBfijf/iEr/i7QD7Cm6JMfxaU1LaV@pgqFoupMf2do7s4ig2ec/QymvfJF4ulM9zxv7y28JQBVW0Qovgpl5@GMPLq@obqeeTRgRxWmZdircNYLqMcfpSUPFsiVzfbDXZq4h87beLf8QD/cm8u8e/Ywr9nl/j3sol/Lz7i36mFf4TZRjXLALHvqlWOEBOITX5mexvGuXQhlPdb76u/24d9zmekpGBAl9rebmRyt7d1412mUhH/IAor4Rt@uAvwbdzmclvvtjOZOuFd3xYF2Mo1tnlp6Nc4f7cFYDNb9a0t43x7e7Sda7zbrmMpb/BndIu/JRVa19kSOqujrWMOcVeCRJZn@EefFzyT@tELGMCcZktbuVRpv7aTLZ28fpYqwttq9IqBy/h6vFfbPXwNsY9e7NVO9r48eLP3@gj8g8b59tOnGQPY4Sngu92oA0pfZLYz1cFgcP7j8yUD@75N3gVuhjhMfM5nuPirktrdHr3O57YA6Rfnm1jAY8otB8RofGIcrJKqp@pa5knmSaFbuCoUL4uXL73D6P/wcAQBzqjwwfMLnUKn2IJmwwr268K4MB4Vet5hsQVOG/4KPXA6hfZo5XDt8OmocFFwC26xmAA3/7936L089ACgB8kGo8IAYRfa8Lw4PHwJwNqQ/Qf4cwqFwgjwHBWu4L/QLdLn3XkBCq3jtlB4KxTOzpQ6U9/bIAKNYtoopI21dNpprK71v725La19WyeNbXWzUccdwA2VZdPnZ/V0o5LKB2dneS6t1dKKWqEtwre35@e7tdPa@XkeJ7pGW4uZp5ncU/hUtzNb4vEk1dquPDkr55D9JCOm8ltPzraXc@heywD1S@C3lc985icCCc@FMyWtXb99@xa/b6@vrrmLHNzv7G0Yij9v8@DFXegFH4yan5U@6RhNc5ym1VcbN7fQaZ2lK2nRrWmMdturxbNRqc1KKg4dtE0dNIfiMuqna6tM395eWwWPtQ09pxVwaMGTnKn9fv9MNWgyxSA7y2q15vvmGAdQ2goA0TZXq9Uz1fTPz9R6qYFpV3Oba8zzc5vLuqrr74pbW5AHZlHSwVtNj1TPT7Ob2/ifdnO7pdFHxz9dR08duIae27oGEfRVeBvdaGxL29LQD7ww3c3tNjop3g246pre0G9vuR/8avoWh7qtA@EYaA3/SP/Qm/z/5//laxaA8nGbQnXYZSurutYc2/rKmraR2RR/1QUgrKYup5dRz0mb6Xr96dLy0vpK/UljyVjCr7Z1tt2Y0efqoP1AQ5ZNr1pMYcWiJDMqx2qxpKbRnUpVLHG@QNe7YMubFeymMaEKH3QpaQYVur0VsnDU/@jbWP@MapTpDabf3gBb80BQmTWx6nR2NiqggGE6qzSrizcp87aSwhzYrSqji9ZB8LV0hZYl1Rt10fTrxYZ6qy7eNG9xbLFU1EmtXF2pVJZWuHt9A9zFJZ3PtIPyVwndEGIHplVBMVRJIfemgZB66kypNu0LgAel7ccbaGZ1dXUhX4LH6Iu1vdJoSXy2l2Z8NkobmaXM0/rS5ibWR4M8Py0oFVz04yuMak7lrZxtbBIWKVyewM@WvXgEaoX4W9pd4q4ifvcWAqXPXBh0rhdYy@vixjev3V4ATxjas6Ztw@jK7nblWRQwAOy2rp2WvaDUe6N2gzYXV3P14tpqIwd1/GHUZlSvSmDDp3dk2kPbvh4Or@3ws@ME5ocPZp8@o/YPv/zJD7/873/41U9/@NVPfvjVz3/9/c9/At@/hO9P@fOn/35zFX9//f2//F9@@PNfgedfw/c/wfc//vr7f/P7/EvvfwPf/yvm9zfiG4vHvwrA@pNff/@zv/j19//8F/D9t@L7i8nvD//6P/D//1v8ofNXP/zrv8Ef8fKTn0Jx//6vfon/P/urv/9Pv8T///V//vu/@ld//yf/jhx/xh3/z7/99/z37/7gJ3/3T//07/7g@zm/P7nz9/sH@H//j@DzcDwfAuch5fpcn@9/K3x@F2pEuQAPAKf98Q//5g@BV/81f/tn8Ab/YdAfhS@JEP7yR9ELQPifZiT6419//6d/Eb79YTJiIgyA/BGE/Xki7I9@@OXv//AX/90Pv/yzH375J9hKcyub2Vo2V7xb@U9BxNUHxMOIaw@JBxF5lAW2oJToiT/Cky2Qa7SkrC7jGCnHPxnu@WkRNUd29klZhffMpzweMsLyn0ToGe5QKULo8gqFFkAJLmDoKr7K0BgquKD85GlCN@eILH16yiAyJI5FpohPOKLCP/MpIdQxJYUvhIjDN8psIUy/MIMwT9hTCIYOkPrALfzFF/B5BgM2MW6rbm@wqpJlG1W2zZ5hxCq8Uzg66R26Szxft6rssmc40kTvXaAQHzrDeO49jo0zFH2bR2XbCoR/Bx7POBiChqC@U8Arw3124fmdiD9SCB7@CwUU3fiVAfCTYdwPXrHXITjiR@ExeDCTjzg1cZSM8TDdCP9ZBEjAyShAiEw2PrAKs8hEXkr4mpnKJcRnIiwThTHReSZAZdgUwLsCE97KZEI2E4rAYG7oRDFl6IwcZWhqOkkYFCdQJpMkGKZMFiqjZNB0bUlkupRZIkuVpc/9CJwog5nkuOMTp/dSVPI43Aj7CCrhyxNkKG6UN0HUuE5FU/2suLYSAtYVjY6iAgUTzS6Ub7xyufpdcWVdgSe9D/GQK3HcErAqnmBsbMEHY2/f5LBNK9sne6cQdnrIiqWCweqFxs3KemlldWW1tLy2trpeKq6sba6srW4sF4qFtcJqqVTcXFnZ3Nhcv1W2f8RGBjs6@r3cLQAa5XL5EkJk1eLqemVchZTkpWyTYsYVwvFNDnRBxOCMdNEbtBPAaZUbmk17BB@mPFLYI/CCT@5WwelSJpapDg4rYjEDTdpCDZqvbKjF1U2VFO5cLlDObLfFgSvr7PUR/BwffPn8NPY83avtPFfW2LPDV7sTj1URaZW92Ns/DV/XeahMuhqC@GbvxYvJV/FArXiBra5ns4ZhwA8@s/Shp7H4TkYpGvN7KXWtUFpXi9nzsQ2q8U0ud3vhNO3iGgxpVtTHKdDI8cCtE36k2ABGu6M2EV15iXYIm0VuQOoEaCkHAK5dMlRs4hmlw/58T3igFzp956IDLHjthRGCILi@DucP3srJgnDS4C1rmiZ@P/cDOdjxz@BujwHPg/ymQrrT0ZXnMMTo4VlcuM1igLPfTpsVFAP5s1Ta3Fjd2FwubWQ3NjdWVmEwsZotlrLF9Y31zUK2WChuFNc2VjeL2Y2VzeUVaAoQurq5rqSA35x2Pg/tt6iq9HRcCw952cLTcjyjs62kWnYbTSrZSGvpLNUKPYYbTF3eOCswSKgqaNy0NKqqpRU0@1ousqKqqCazWGp/f6ewv6@qz/AFZ652CqrawpfVjUJh/Zmq2hSyA821BIk6@La3hlNcqurgy05tfx8hfMCX0gbCUNVLHsJfuvJlHaK5@LK8jACYqn4bgisAcI9jtEGpBvylUHi2o6pDjt4G/EG8Gn9bIWT38AUDMNE@D9mBMFX9UiYCJUpVj3k8kdVzWd5aTVUP@EuthiC@osKv8kJ9jS81@kAiH96Ac1X1AhwXPgwfVbUJTuRfVbXAZY1N8OuBCzeWuQNTVce8HFgSVR1RbNO6VNVz6Q/5AD7Pn5udQcu@4J@xz58WBB1AkDMa7u03v/yyeXHR9Me1vS@PKeirr56bH8ZDv3nRFAmb5/DxMBUEXfbGkx8bg87Pze7soK8hyJ0IOh@f24ThufktYCY@F5hR7/wrDPoKgmatVwiA8OlB5CZ@nvXg@cxs8iD5oSB6jppNtYIsi02nrRHjmll60NFv@g3DZedAM5@QpCqjlPLaWiE73NBzq0@GG@raulpegqf6RF0GJzQNVkgXGFPTZ6qq1zcbT9T1VbWcfvIkl35cfMLU9U21rK6vg6TXK7co5DT9pq2NsqNqATzy@S1s0NgE4Rn2PaKDKG2oIDrBW0bgLT9su9BzgJRm8M3lFAzvVwXGKtPwBEo036a1SC2dXi@l03q6AmkXVMBFoEIW3lhkibEKMgMw3ixBct8eDH2XFSq3Uzn7l@VgYPq4GE05lJm6Bt0ZeOOxntOfpzC4yZaXmqtb2/9k6vPf/JNZn9m@@FF457xWVFK3SgsPdVnZVFI3yu3N7da2zPFrNh6bGTmAYI8Zu8gsKotpLHh6Oakx16q1i@OanOaq7cC4bdlb8VKLi4tKaut0W11WD43zcFJ7O0/rJGe4iIILDsbZ@dZC5rea8c4Z20/lEhGgnld8Gy2zW3hrAp953ljFirhgQSrzW34gE6UKMJUKTheqKWw9Vtcb4loeO@MF2vouRTPT7OimPXTJNKf8EnUXzSzzfrreABb@7pXTvdlYzm3TirIGHHxLTGEd0mqfknI94QQ6ghI4sEcDDTSdVdJ0oLr6J5vv1t9tvHv5@vD14f7TQnmjvEFEP5N8ki2mi2mqxqfQVTnHe/cosueggX7yVovfuV9VUuV@enklvRwGnlVTnIrgxqah1evFBqsvNxp1YMcG0@G1Wi09Ka5uZFbKxXWmp7ZL60ZgjlMNsatFW1nX4YXmKkvF1Nvk5zrxckXLakpq4@X7TzR9yE/@d0rkyucZW7zduoX/7dv61tbtFtqHwgP/@c/tLQ@nfyyAfKFH9EnEi@JE4b8dNxrnqcZ3uS3@v4U/O4ecCOraqqqn3le3gUfenb87TympTaaWqF4zeT4h2WeM6yxLLv3ZwRL@vYs8lkAJWwrf7K2lgK1uw5ge/PL5/Jn@eyVQaDY31zbWUspvgFx3WOhBaGiy0rZtPxj2Ztms1HznpYn2PG5otwKOl8OPeLTrU3m5g9R9GCo/aJSF2k/cTyhEMS@6EyXpNw7yuIMAfRUFXQ5d3MPaxHk4hT8gS3C2hPtMcaOUrtwojwDW0BrQ5gP4qSjKI7SCx1dNxsuyx8FAx2mKgq48eiTkcjAwgsE5AsdEwjNXrCi3CpLHbLUCRocr48oT311lok251@cHMnTHjCcKqG1wRY42RmG@MYSXWJtjAaVZYpQjYY6F49k/4tGawzaisn/wYg/SwLinTdYjIrXqN/HocSreQltnYfcCNMDzd6uCUhQdIwI48OT9tN7DLVyWRjEzrIjhbbJCgVhZVswSJlnWFgnr@NqA5Ai@DeIuAMA8d42XgC2di2xFGQQ@VAggIZaOekl0mP6FlRW1h4cV1hs6u5EbRTQMZVusFO1kEbCgMvi1QZTQ6rXEMcrViMwErdjIQtVW@IYDLYwnfCJC3SpLg2yvwquqX1G@1ixQJzxfq3zXe/zYetev9xoVvVcd4DOT6UHPfak5PMrSoNqrAnv0606jMqhnMk6j2tO/1vAdTyvHbl4oRYEuygYld6uAC1r1BHr2Y93Nfec2svt1NwMoD7NLP65@zJrVAqozWadazHaz31aLohyQ56D6MeNWzC34oiVWYjMHKCsZs5LwwiSXWrf6sW42UD/qQsJMZh8KA3gG9W4m09Ah8y4ETiesdB8/NjPd7VGlm8vpGOvd8pP9@gAcjUwV38uauTV68rE@hPRlDZ5VyKarA/KQTtD6NsQd8KsAjXmdRqhzHEl9GwF6vWp16cdPln68VF1Y@Fgf5XqNLCd/uRBxAyI/QuQrsc0y2tKPdTZBElqM09QvnPIXBghHNetkMkDkbD@WkmO49GMI6WcyEutblJd0mYm08kMOExs8@MnFdAwqGe3S8dEBncI@aOFWN0hbCyzHEdH5HsW@AwNpE/caZ@mIcpNiYJi4XQkDz0ZPnigya7GnAHJG4dK0mYkDcrpbw8eVQbqpi2@rvk@@zhLDUuaGA1E6LhuGvMtrseZKookaXOBbdYyCYuCmcFvhEovvJAFhQ9ID4pD0wHg5lCJIJCEnRMyqCITakhUEqVBOtPmRALT5GeUTqtxhywcRwtGAxjwDDSf7oUqyCfjJARdztig/cEBTUR5BIRAHLIPTYNsgyNjjx0y8blVZsbSOfQFGw3gfMkWMNIUpZP4ATAEGYvkBeBTlIWUCuD3CENwplcho5XfLSGx01CBB5kOW73c0aL@jNnQDvs0X6aZzNLAuHj36kKmuCITgn0YskB7Cbn@TEt19me0cvjx6fbp3/LJ2Ar8wgtuI30Igb/qZut@jj/d2NB2XdvtY5nHR/uYrizEN9OEBnmmKF3m12FevX7BS6dVuFk8kA9Kn@FQldKjlEJId0InPgeH5F/lr59LJJ68NxDuXaGMRXVKYk9cVIDrUOXejzcfR3uMAZ8OgMxfHKCVuBujZQSCuLcnJq@DoEAvaht3D3cTQCsU1J2SzLc1OycgZl6@zZDrvOxcO3e/V4QAS6enA9wFPTu1DwetJWubARI5WNjcKhTIrZNFRlI6SdCxLx4p0rErHmnSsS8eGdGwKR1FCLnLIMCZeXl6LnOuRcyNybobOlULkjCCslCLncuRciZyrkTPKbSXMbW2D4LKUpCY1XdvHsOLKhgzDkwhgVISeqwCmOOm5AoiWpmJC8pUpT8hvI@m5vlkQGR3kDzFSqbQWvYP0kXGrGscqy/HI8pz5m/CEvkrh4z9i2D3fB6m0N8L7mIDp9DLDzZSKAmKXWV3bBGXAHoCWUt0H/rf1Mj9kwB@Xow2VCKFaDN8hOV4HAGmKdLUYZ58ZwaVZwRxaaSY0fuQDCwkT240qkORYlhM9LYe4kvCLQ11AAYsUnROjxGNgHSS3r8o8T/3hzCyX784yAXBmllNIcbirs1IhbTQCXpVJqf8naFWZH9dTbKptUAPERZLEAxMViqdNVG@KZfXX3//if2O//v5nv2I//Pmv/t//@D@i@z/gz/8OOgsrhRF@@jNGC@3w868YLavTEn@UiOIvl9UffvFLeP0f/h374Sc/40F/@hdqdiUEBCHoFaX8@T/Dnz/En/9Tza6GEX/@xzwiJlGzt0pCtdIg1k//mjHIDaGEwH7xl4ypGVAwNMF5dd7GG7G96RxASIY6uRqT4fwXr@EBGhf0jApwxVsxestgBegx4L6JNyNGbQ/UGb6EhFLaMq0O7j8WXl6A@o@FKowXGBfAb9ctUHrEREcaSv8HrMzSGYyjoyF2C8c4JMNF@UW51SgU42bUPGCHV3kIUHRJUYgJDG8V4G8aCYwDA4ctNCItch4R9H2FN6/KDkSVnEV3tigiL5kaZ2LE/XV0iY8c6iLTYjfED6mgu2sUsUG2GMswIW4mqg1ymfSBIWO0bT2elDzsXh@qBJKF9EbC4gtRITsJLqo50Wz2DvcnGgx@mqBiXsYlUphRlanqPXGR0iK@jhrXcjI@x1dEqBfKy43EJvhZkdUf/ehHqhLzKyAP@S2NIMQKxUVGGFRMBpViQaVYEODMYZKsWS2VJnCgjgPlYvLAB54sJqKSySLmwpYj6wHRgLEgnynNtrvDoFOdBk0SOSnspoHHQBYbVdFOzlySOdtM1acSAMxkmupkXc4GXZiKM11Rs1MitRM@idqaDymRJtYoiHrKJJXCmituzqq5ZIZ3gC42Mg/MqFT4HTPKPTCjtdX7M5qsVkybAD@fvveLHSkmQgkfAeMNP5XooLBr/AWwXiSOEGOfnJoOQ56aGPI0rz2mzbioEPzz8gjSxO2EfuxgUhzEvPIGNp8eeNr3YMjhoRYcu9541r3m4jbhC9fz7SB@uIXDt/@6aTxexfIuXOjVsngUqiOu3sTleX4qV7JfCXs2oYXu8BuTETQnFGqe5@eO6wzOz0H57Lb1iID4ali4JzOt4FXL4Iql10LV9rCveXik80C/HybpuzzZqWNdaod9EZiGTGoMBnSW3YXBF@vgJWyBx0mCReTXsoFG2hxodO5ax@t5F7br4ckymHoC/EEEGxEy@33CJcvMLLNiGIlBtGZlTV0k/fqzk7KvS3iNoExfSgJIECPL/EkaI2X9Gdmdz82OJ5P5nXw@vidxfE/uxrft@MFgEmfyxNkefH5e1staBAEiRmgs349GVhwmNYVOApXQGy8A5QkejGLLDizo/hDTGkStiehGG/gjG74FtPtSIP5mHv3vrkCZfO@h1UfK7MkY5E2P7uujIVpA5/K5lq1B9ANdjwzHYtmFrL37wLzEQIdGeFmmkuBycWsvNMx@33bxyjj@kYDv4Xm0G5riezImqvLAGTj5V1l2WZpfRbvnLbtrju2WJmJmY3BliY9ts0Xy6mEFR0FHQs/jt75qhWwxoYrREQwUqTyHZczsla7PZysexQm5hxbjCMOD@fSjibtJ0YyToFW@BuL5IEFTdEobnY3XH/fH/NiWLr9tXshR3v/wmnyFp9ncSxCgA78VsZiNstXvEp/HWlikB/QIYVwjWWTa/Cy7LQ@08ak6/DwS3V9SmmUIE1VlLSe0k3k17txV4zGukDzJtZKHseR9TPdgnouxGgcWibCdz@tCpiDvmN2uZWlxiNznzhrz3CmZgH5YY547p1c5nyFQw5Qk6QZ4BVWV6xe64oDzAJ5X8HwDTwQIY9BzzlCybKjXyikvCumZ/ZjWInzqFuqiMSrq8XXEWCxFunEi9zbM05qbpzWVp5XIM2wBySxjkRQrkaWoBayeu6qga7cHc6QzBuHIHR53iW34uJ7p49rrTdpJl50sS1@lyyCQ03a6vKeBUE630uVdcgTp8gk5LtPlr8ERta30p3RZNguM4MMrOZ6ivxDh@G6lyzuafqvgtfOBzNdIl8M6hThP@CtR5JZPrzbFqr8XzqraeKUvKpVZhhwTwMPDYtUbWfoW4J@iiqNPIXChykpLFBkHIIlOI9Zj8Hyg2zDwUmZfm9V9lOXUlJjfiOZQIDxTjU2qIJcMSR6lU@mkMOKIYShNPsITEES5WZ6NEStOjczuQ0fk7uBlykDsZP5EPYP0gZZG4XWIHJ/E6UbpZX0lQfAKfBiemHgenlPoyOwIIzQG0GeghUR9n76jUFjXE8do8tqP19D0HAFWYk5G4bVEYGMyHXQ41E0ps77XTzIJheJqnxNPgx/RKJF7J5KRVBAtc04weYuSoWCIN379ruLE0iFqCRGEgfVCg7eysF8gWYxBkayLaaq88QEKMZnTonOtbGTbXeGkeFzcZKmvmNcNybQ8S5JcSTEJiQ3cNT40Bzz3aF0G95J/3vBVpgQVHHBEALGUYS5cvnqfob97XH@XCrUkwkQGsxTr2V3ptHp9Zy87gXk3yna6AjEwy3b1mcpRmENEchgdxDTzu3htSsXH20q5ks8zDaFPaPuSbOGY4B66TY4tOCzUEvyrpOclTsxeluYTaloj6V4ZUmkxMCcBhxc8xDQq2t248oLPqmIMwT4aHp9dwX6yguOVh/CoAP4EyXkr94cumVdFbZtOJ4pWLviqg4dWYuGhsDFPEPdkvxaaaIHH4fnx7uGrF99Ap7u@vq5PL0Vgq4W0UT@u3LlMEA5bSlk81w@PIibbiY7nDxbOXHXapIw8QBkwad2Gs59o47qQZTF5PtF2IR2PG6OogHUZNQMzIZVQ1TGxy3YEXfkVOdqSKYBI9RbonaXRGq4aIXfggs75OXVf5@donHN@LnoxrJpwGek3KXFZbimy11BSSWsm0riCqcOzcAJg2KNtRHICThyLxe1QUgDnYCBTh6mG7sCRxg44P0Rb0@RavrZcxNmJg3boQ3igUYZWWsEhbGkVD@HgqTA2TnySaaXIZ4ErOng6fND3XDrfl85MJLUdz6oP5NQroT10r00yA@G50NkhMYy4QZZcF/NcfnB7wNPipjmaQpa0yTL7wqAVn9ImDDkunT4/9jU0/Qh0SkQIk40W0LjZtXuA0gnw7ozZ5JcO1Epn37m4AEbKi3ufuIHLqQlJc147tyOPM0uxN2bXacmDtYVNGB1qL@aBgZxa4jy6gJXWQJvazAJloy8QFs1kGJ45VyAjLYoF33V4rHPnRjaWdkEb68lnUX50hLegnWPN8o3Hjo93PF2ZbozO9PkUn5oWi5YkB2Irl/IENEUchVmldUoDbdT6mppS5dFo6ORmE2bXkie1aXhGYFl55JLgQQswZnHbGlBwXVTaaHlND01SXfYFWy7R9fWQH2mplC3A4Ct7CegQBkkRWW7dJwSM@kVL/QIXE5VHKZSFnNcwvWRldNMR2xEvswUBji@oYFPmTUC@rMZelmGo8WhGxguamgEoGVVXE5Agvlj9eMQl73RSEIogHj7XFNv2fZeiKVcgShhd2CnMiCt3GPaSZS@aDybsenEwFTfUbAv7NX7LTVZ9jRZYZZ4J9R0GnnyJorsyKbtzRWmuSQ@0k2ZLtEG0nehoVB8Th2gsOO5dCFCPQhyKcobMv74IyvAFHLISJJCJLBY0oo1@L25EEbSjxmMCCo1KrEvRinFsEMF2AAKlDfTMql@g1epjSEhdLPR3@iy1qVBJpAfkgr5LltxqzlApqbA6RkhJELw20T@0fVXI4F0KrjvO8jbzxY3C2ibZTzM3O8j26puN7JJVVZk9cEy3Fwz969blhde5AmWB9T80R9b447eMra4w3FVSesy3QhfXqnna7bxOxwVs0tE5i/IsAtpQf6YyRltk8eiDNGPhTqTKAu6Bhk8Wf8pqZYpL2VJPciE3ou7V1xpVt1qo9Opuo@JmMvogUx1kihkNPR4X9QpIWj7tUh80yCoyv8ReStNFPOkS51a9NjvyXKvjpQNGV@XF1/Roe5lsQD2zH29PVzDq8Py4Txv5yewlGuK0F/bC5kRKx5PxBuO@jaIxtPrs4j2j@PNouLZSmQ7HEj56hCbKFaGbxgtwo/SHza5jgQwieqKKgeaK5bIwurcY8i0IKPRzuCfHBXogDYMrMtTy@mOR2OFRzmVZtmIgtzXsu/TsQ2LKWE3gyXM8l9yHaDwKJ28iOgPQ1PXoHCt0v7DdsJ/BfRJ6Ba3I2YIMkzsqMD7yDe1rOAf1j3ZBwGOLiahkY8x0YdFLvnUHjQpIVdtO86BHH4a9PvXvBsdXUAQvXTnvm44fpjSCIV6YpLEiEsORSGMNoOMWN@xdgWIZrxpZFzixQIvbWB6Ed0Qn5wLClolXjoFsxMUdhNfyKM0jfquPBp0gn7jiaIi0VAxdVDUQDk@pSvfTZUbzDBXwoi6nEgv9AKFY1jnBPQjumYPOnOAOwh4G84J9CMa7fuYEOxDMbU5mh3sQzjWpOREGOIsG7Ho@8M4HptPVuME0mlrfcoGtsUxGEjZkAcYrhtdHMj0TpudsgdcOZ7YEe0H7JLbiEZClNdF48D3iFgrFgxM0zhexPDlN2A27NzMx@QQkPqecQOxi/vpSAj6LIQDtD0Qpmw6XmfPaDgua4B8Dup0LrG0g1jL79OkuzAQjJvmv2JDcx2sI5zljJeTUiuDwq0iieuWJPopEs9MI0/y4dJM6aFQO2ShLkQjhbStq120H9EVIqqOWE3njkFJnTyKfetBg5VB6RHTkzeJ@OpamuAdHnNQis6wZOa2HU9VEvoeUJvTIzUhY4D4sszJFziCMnUvG3obYITUn@MxK8IxopZ9b2IeVJgX4UaMm2lS4oLVANdwWCM5Az@T1GpcJHNhiusz98eIUJwnMmQOM71c8BwCDLcABezYpxmWf6LgGt/kBOV8orWRpCp9HuY3IJIXVQ@j0D9C4kHCiyx7iWfJJkcRmkGYqelhupNf2ZJObKB6X9LMLV@dGY@knacSRTfMTcd0T6CXLrMDCjTEVdnu/HPrtKHMTVV9C3wm0@bJCVrrkxIew4O0cQt/LZMkilBosQfEhXVvdv7dLok2eszulaOniXPrIaS3etudqYIhVJRmOOHOAMgAU5XiqrNC5tiPRKXa3ng@kcpONtDC6TZ24AlT2ihIX5zic26fOO@4bbs0hisRD0FIQNUxfYua0pW4LarBMZ1jnWM2cyEhPaNMXntfSpMIkFAaCIC2gIVKWbxcK1SquXkbZQ3ZC6WUXwopa9rsV8FkQXtSvgAcqn4I3EYmlC2o2FWw2Mf3GCeiGIQrH3giykqs7OBnEpQ8rT/pj7FAFejQzkZT4uOeLdgYLOU89cUI8qDumixNvdKwTDa23VPQPKwLjbMNAO9o/THVwO2OWge@RFruHb@JDF6fiGKgTh5UuZ5n0SojN1paK2URncvwmtZAfBj7djWq7VwwvJFdSzHb5GfNlvKcxt4ETsXjNopAmNO9NkzzAJlBTmJvh2teauIoRd2mrusL3/NGkUFHBoyNoXr5rX7VA6@cW8X0vGNHvGAYLBWPYH3gUIjKivYHsk/Mp2q9eoFVaMWIQ6GwRnCiOhus33HfM56JyRa4gFfFYDD0Goo4pSeCqZ6qK9YeIivm6ekMJDNu0OogE8t4nPpyC6iJOvlUCWfW4lw1JgYuD4OxyK94@zc1hFqSdBGN6h@LjexEd3IemEJHvxThFoQlXDOl6Xh@ZHKfaMP0WEIAT/tHJ6e7e8bEhjp/lKwK4isDnidEEgzYEimtUxTQprgbgdkxeKY@wsAib51eNgJP8JRphtoJM2BSukZycVrjfk5cgV6S3qWKE8XUenUhCy8niLUBaFoTVdB/0KKRdlEyLJcvJZDJyjBSP7qWGaVloaPvS7nmA8Q5d217ktHgUkQOdSBGZfybMP6hjno0QeR6emwrPJcINHs6RimIZVsePIpXjkdTUTRTvlqlRtOxUXlUGhT54Rbt3DM@P4V25K25gwCDNiSJvh1XJuTIM2EoE5GIh72bUPg9ZSKQJGTwMr/Nwwd8lUfMhlom4T5P541MRFWSTjaswCZngUsN1uvxq3yiEJCzDbSs8OdY3sR1vlGJCRIiTHIgJvOcUm@12NYKSKUqJQ21G3d56qhpiSuqJNomGzm8DnWxYM9pIjEqUZ4YIN6KeBPKh4IUYCIKJjMZky92Wicci8TgGFmMtyGwVuRM72cChaJNNvIrT5p/wRzb2JHIyXmp24COO@YgXnq9kJQlEQndBnU2mpDQZ@EObe4pC3dGLRHmPJyHOFhKvPByBWh26zlbmafP1trY3dFsLoZyICwopKaboHoYISkcRipJ951UhBt4qv8kvKV@aPdAKu/aIxW4RVxKLmXgBbQBtwIYC@iwY9vtdR@ybY9e0XMbLWSyt4mJPBDGmNBjKARrg8PhZdInFR0hksEOEfI12HFFAgFcS01WWDO/KAtHadgDkwFBq7pjfsonbzEp8SdFmw4BfSk13b8eQ4DXHW094c6mhyIVbXtQ2b9/uAFQgKLjn8yuZvXZZUX5v6FiXO1@yUqGwXiwsF2Mkk1PVBWN5JX6jchhQKhQLhdXiiqLseP0xNx3RLB1hreQQYJa9wI7@DfCmfYV3WSk16DEoIp4nGdj@ld0yFOXYbtEccHNIFEFWxsut6ZQK2kePPqBb4XlCeN1rkOV3ugKH4RP7Z342gEWGy1kF12j7tt9zBnwl17vit3rLdem2h3eQ00Q0LglzemCinj0AoizpLIkS7fsXuJDuQtvxgRqmuHLTbHpXdE6HIAPoqQ4eb0QLrApuUkUI8cz4fX0xTCA/q2s6PWSnGQjgLpaIAhIBKFpraNl34qAQEp@Jg7xLtOVZdFm6KWsmD9LPo7YCzd32HZC@EYGpVihZDHeo4NPnByfs5HD/9G3teI@B@@j48M3B7t4ue/YNO32@x3YOj76hk1LZ88MXIF1OWO3VLvi@Oj0@ePb69BA81NoJpFQpQKm9@obt/ejoeO/khB0es4OXRy8OABqAP669Oj3YO8myg1c7L15DZ/1llgEE9urwlL04eHlwCtFOD7OUq0ymROnY4T57uXe88xxea88OXhycfkM57h@cvsLM9iG3GjuqHZ8e7Lx@UTtmR6@Pjw5P9hgWTNk9ONl5UTt4ubdrQP6QJ9t7s/fqlJ08r714MVHQw7ev9o4R@UQpn@0BlrVnL/YoJyrn7sHx3s4pFihy7QDxAMEXWXZytLdzgI69H@1BcWrH32QF0JO933sNkSCQ7dZe1r6EwinaPVSBetl5fbz3EpEGSpy8fnZyenD6@nSPfXl4uEu0Ptk7fnOws3dSYcqLwxMi2OuTvSzDezMoa4AB1IJwcD97fXJAdDt4dQp9xuuj04PDVzpU8lsgDGBZg6S7RODDV7y0QKTD428QKtKBKiDL3j7fA/9jpClRq4ZUOAGq7ZzGo0GGQMTTeDHZq70vXxx8ufdqZw@DDxHM24OTPR0q7OAEIwBMzPdtDTJ9TaXGegK8uBOYVZGcm6XqZAf7rLb75gAxF7GBA04OBLcQ2XaeC5pDW84rM5fc7lzAm17lE1Mhdx/Cs3O4uwcaHz@sT438X0Ons5FcvEuEQUcTBsKrWAWlvuq8ZTeHF@d4zzYOzcNkfAW7F1xk8dBLHe85OVPuOBtQLJRTglTq/PxN7RzGuSfn53r2ISkTaNyXQuxyvyuWLsrY9cwWDfMTc0txQm0/FmfpZPnBFvG5lsfh5IPO8vmWLZKhcQgCltNE4tAnANZCyUhWI6bLYlnSEnNyrohOJJucLJLLm14AP@6n6IX3DTEPEM7cbiGfxzEsoYEny7EQf8iEDl0TJ6@RHYDTpiyNwLYvL7RCPDsc8osJKl2mobgDGAZeaPo9yZv2xUTy3GR6QhZteUhZkcftyGNw@CWn@CZIxkS9GD6VTONTe/TQJTaUESiFOs@KDIWE9Yn2mCfH/dt8rlCvhEe10HFrL2s/OniLg7lCaaUy4f889OdtC6368OxA6O/qlK5Bj@cNHgEamIPDLyCJM@ZLqvl8LA1oZaRPhpHxLKAORrp2WtCnYlfdsalbxxOI@HEM8fTQGfvOKI49iOEvj2svn73e3wfJidiubKyur1UUcaKRP/hRlj@/wXzwjHeiLmjR1w6oaRQUayU7oPfsTx1GGDs9EWsPI@IJ37LSyBMveQ13JnMdgZ9fxqeBsLgBnuDk4iFmKh7C5Kv8GuMFRfLrzJYpGEBLFFXH0uBd9ajhm6AqEQ9YfBdyd0y1NsIfhB02f9nEwwIJBhIsZvf6gzFwLgwuSO6p@9Kgk8Y2ZLaFUQxV8nHflDZInDAoM8nKFW0c6U3wdqwWQa/Fisb2StVOKQGJhUks5CF4dKQlZHHkBbIFc08HfH4k@A2c34jDFzEIj9KqDU6AjPthypw8HJHPOYuGISA3tqtQRY8fhzltMZxI1QVSfP4/eTRfvDUQKtyggU0AlpZHIZ3DEJqEfprW2Q3nVDw1BeFUBMeKd@DcWcURUCryyBnxLk/oYxxWdGAfeV2HeSgyyjcySkjOBJl@J3oQ/P@KNJkBfwsGnAA9ohbJYccd2g@kJEHltILRKxHFuZYWYzEztYiaca9vIjC38YrphAUTZngjvrAEJBC1M5Ye3/AjW7UZBEAmx3mNePsN70fvmDByekpt9xFf6fddq9fX5IGnsquYgtvIks6VlSZy@KLzJfwCi2X3As@ve0r7aElm4IALpFhzzL4IVA4jUySZg4XOL9GkR9jKiTWRDEXZwiN2KoimJRv/SFgYRb1MS4begio6/zDVcDkEz2xMCHy5AiIFCNk@xQssyAZ5biOiM8uNlvQ0y89EL46Hk4MIpH6ZnZL5c2C2acyMXZGwVUajaMwS4XzREmdiNu3BNXYXXQ6dbLQjaEz7gszEMRMxFxmqEVL46gZQnTrZ6xB7mqZEfg2xf@1euni5hc2nuGQMI3HCZnyLu8FemnTYZvdh5VajzDNI1u1k/gcu2a1bfL0Sp@Zo5A654Ej/iyCiCGic16hdQj8UUcm0LtFTlTzqXOecETwor5wouTwzEsYMdCLwLKX/du6AAHllwgaWqWduOIlU5h1Z9QupvqCLt93Q9Q26xDxzFQoFyIEPGswKNQhRRr0JjTSnWxvhl9i2gManZdCcrq@NpjnsmW7b7DndMVmdfvA6bj5wh0Efr@9WVTU5G4gHraAJOuA@sNlbx2151wF7Bs0BJ5JOXr0@OUpO/MVmvnb4zBdjX0Ee7BnlrEyBb@OelMBrD6Bq7Aobi7t2/Gi6h@YJxUwLTWuN0QM3/vjEQJBvL9SMv3z1mn1pu7YP@uAR2VyyF45luyA@QJkiK8ygwyUNRt/H3E9E7mwfdRea2akw26FJnXBuTxEZCGhZZC0NmiIg7Itjq3FufgysHpsTNKYLHJWrJSeVOl5f7LbASVNUNvkUZ3vYzSp4Nvbbg9PnOBjnA3Oam4FuTc714VwiV516fLIWCuOb7mAMRFEmJ28A7fvmbgxGmy0AojKfnDSo6@GdOC2c9usGUFS8KElIAepBoKnazhUexkvTcA@pI7KzFdNmEd0qYv9qlh8PLEVHovaUqPayeCa7kWWrm@zURt5lR13TghEWOxli8uVl0AOfecEAo76sMVYoFYvFXHEZp2hfn9QMagj4lSe0KsrBy6PD41MgpDiCSDJG2Gci8elQVG6NBeTI4dGoUPr3KJBlfJCYpfdEPFTB5TkJaoWvWKhlFereMnG6F0oYJNVhmpLFKXnPp4NZcbcNsFCiOUKuwTUKX740QjnFoGfpaFh5Azp1LSGetFuSErxH3LrAV11cD31PickPBIA9Ij9I5dPIoCWOFYI66dm9EHtnIHt3k0dQJs@UDQnG51KBOdLZNGpJQD09Dqdlo41EgKcz9YIrywfZYl4By6EJi9xyBDxDskkPS2M2na4DbQDwsjoedjhcXMmKoCmI@ImzCtV4eJYhdkiEy4zToKB1tbxeGJVjpSjhZjvh3w/GlsdSFzDMxpFW0LftFp1ENezzo5Yw3IBW3oWeg2/DK0dnMCmpAtlN@iBs8Mg7kH3DLu7Nx72UTV7niiwNcJXcvnnawWE9BwQlOhlQI8UTcbUZI@wsw3VenardBIbAtDoSYs5GSgDRz@KiFGAF9U0MQS5ilyxu9@lSfU/us8SEdNhj0E8GICy@qmsnAyR4LLtwTkXgTFoNEZjYwimR4fuQuDsxB5Z8wfKi3SluStN4GaFwYz0k5r6DR5TzuQGPXXj4i5ENSTG@RmjTGuHUxlC85LAI8CZjFqdjQqzwgLZYzNIMmLmZMJdnw8wJmGKx8sC9og1xmIrYgpeCn7bhgXxEQkTF/9KTope27XU9vsAUlv6i6zXxXEyQFJAbPsbZqGLj3jQCSxA6Hso3aSbP89ySRRKoi71NUndhW9A@7G22JWcsts9cXlEioMrbEu0JY9R3UXMiJ/6IFkVONXE4KGodE6eDInrcF2Q3glUFSOGjllnUMtESJx5f5JxM0kskKU4kEcglkzQTSUpKtBN8onYxBYp@fCZLJvUSskqiGmDVsIIKSs8c8dFNgTb40TQNHsmd2HFYaggGwYh1i4V7BjF6Q4mOwEgs2/M85CuZ4JHFt7qo0pGiheR5UiNpukdigGIlwsd0zIqriQLpggz0Eh6voUtkRLm2KIkbk1RhgXmAkii2j3u1tHguepml@iZfNcRYAXZs8azrRANcpVfhb4lpIoNcHFkeCY8tEKIQCE9HW9RhKMurRcrBghL1zPQWE3BQgwqX32QyxrsBTUu0Kym5Q5jcOSW7ART6c3CUk8L3Vweg13Ff7FFiouEEFT48Jl4oefYIhme0xkwgqP8JZ6yFJz8zIpQeAvl6lHND9hrJUsyNPdmVzIoT61VCKtwVWRI7pNPcyPN7GyIdziGgvOPRY6R7gZPEgnSyC04HnGSkpTgD2kzuWQ6XUEmyxYQuT5udIYCTVS6Ry06USokdFSNKONmNKImeM8EkWuwNr8FhX/CDgjkgXUmkQvrPq3A0d4w37LnxijyeqPZ5HBHCkvV@F1uEkWW938UWPHKs2u9mC3lWdEhaSj/JF4ma4CRAo0QxYqA5pbgMkgGjeKzRRCxCaNyInxVjd7UZ2MakqpjrVKZUpZBE4mi4ZB70GPGKSYmN3Al2BOLVw9poRKWFPs66tFvhiRei9OEQaVtNdgm8NicPesJCyxyojho6XkkSJgCJzSfBxJi5x2036cSgNB@w0BgUT0W96CR39ybAyl6loE8rlPJ0pAj5rZnI56ZPqYqGWOXp@3dC6zKBNRo8eX4LY6vKjBVf5R6sMjGskqWL1VCSxHMg5R4EKfcASPkYJNGwl6G/JGfKx3OA7ftAnJ1Nw6DHOxhICRggaVsOTmLjOPjaHN8HcwGUrRTZ1JncqixMEOnJ98F4MgmDzl3vhKtxwrNj4qzbR9v3Jk89m0vZJK/MwCjEKjWNVhbRIqlN410RT6pKNLY1LpsdJxwJpO6vaX5OhEiMpsSdcBEolTy1KAQWtf/iHPplY9WabA8c8cQ0DGjLymc2BwMJwWeY@FaxMEFMkCXHoSIgSYi7QyeFH41WJ0@XwAPl5ybT7y3JUz7hE5t0KkLRuMRKcJwcwkXCSfZWUr7NGp7dm39qZv59rw86TnsmAhS/h/P4fFJqQqRHqunE0PpBfdnM/my6XHG9beLst4c38sdTRS9B0XFjOjRq174Wvf9dkEVZZA38Fpp8XfLIHCS/mIkkLrSbYnKLucNe0/aVhzR1nsLABx8jzedcRUmlWM2CIbM4eYhugKLjkW2RJarByAgBG/ZxvSbgxp3YuHGOzOYMPBkXb12n2IaKWdAcbc82XXEUkegwL3xcvwjjZvF4dNzcRTk4rgWEDuzY9Od7fudHyxYhaJF8B1krs@seuZpuhedYZKOcBFpc19TGyTEt952j4IRaDcUqTyoqkndwMXSJa@ZCXwLFXJ89BfYQ7ekuhQiYeF6WYsA7AfpuHi3PJ@awH5IyrJoHkHKWuhXOcj9A3Ro/VN36r0DJyQpVYm6hPYgOtnyvUJsc5NOFt/Lg696Mo1venO7vJw48aY7lqKBn@6uFQgEPwZm63Q4XKHCV2PHyydh5nBPP96@/8t8085g0eZ/dzOvsEAeIirFxaQL5BJcmhtDfxI7TwvkcF3flfAh4TH4CT4uRGacTGre/OSXmI5BIPLvM3mMBsXzvmbyHGhRHPmQQUKS9GaRGNfRKlWZyQB70aOOJOqFJGgGjcbPYtYALH9XtG@WRuOKR5vnwOh79JtqGqD63u10vy956fre1oPLdockE@/vxBAUeBU0JeeMJ6HqILLOvnG7sigyMgrh5Xdvoehf8jiW8P5fPftJeJt/u40qahv3YsX2xN@prav2dCowJRc5gMTNMbeD2ngsVuiiVltDvB8sPJAO0HxS7Z/Y1i@g0GRn6QLGXKnIBRst4iSa3Dsb5lB0oMhpzaIkoOj8XhtPs/thI1NnoGh88x9Wg6Bis4HY52vpN1UslmRM9JK56Niq2kYYFDkPghEcgPizFbQUPnfrtPzi7jTMHuLmR5njDLbGx88bi5ZCT8diy2NWg3YbmxWfit@VRYxIcicpckawUkDSiYn372yHoM1q6HaT5AXZoanMydq0EIvVSI8vSw0F7Iw0QfqcyKrIFiuYH9ESzia9z0Kz3h3RPSiTPaBoODSim5Q4mOMcEivKFVf32WqvVamyxn8mwWu0ZOHI5VntWY7vo8ewZ24X3Z/j@uFpaXa1wy7ld/QY8n0nPW/YMYFAXhHey7cIrhNFVSziUwipezFcXs5XF8@rWdiXI12vPGvn8Bbj@7g9@8nf/9E/zNfHyPb48o5f6uzCSYRj5Retm8fFtBd/ru430YrO@2G@kLyrIZSjuX/uB2TVj28QM6x/kXly5c97SGWi0erWaZulPn7jrbBA5/ciJlxhEyc1uv2NSckYQtqvpWvrxY3BtVdM/Tut4cofwN0P/j@DPdJTltF5MpKXl49rJzsFB/J6g8P7RNmqauOBuCuM0xw0cKNT7lFw9z9WZYbBGjr0P0UOD7nMeMYkiS6PFKEfmO4GkLB1iJgFQc1AbOTRIq@bqxbXVRi6VSqncTM0hzLh9KlkgccMobq7WCy7I/khaMFEYWYthoi9aZW5bRzAyIBExfoXvWtV4e3yQKRx0NOGd4uyG0X23Kr/GdRy7Xi92tS6eITJ573p4bm108zpdvC4BWhNnG0wC5KZ3MF6mOkFLQIaVK96hA5@upvfi/hu2ItdqxB52rzu@6OJ1lLQNIbiG9g5018UVyV1XnjOIOfCUTbuNS4m8jRDFYtvgSNWycXepa@F8PXS0bhePpeUqlLyIGHQy4DDUGcTJFm3cRa11XW5877XBqeOl8fLCZaq3DB2XRHWC6yJdOnSFp5cta6kP2mCfx0SqwntkuIplILNpYfLwaNqEsa@LlLREhrtJgVn7dbSRKzbk8fi6YD210@v1QJ5wJguNYUBf6@HgDqcbgDiYwqCzXKHRjdn7rvt@1oXMZP9HWfPsStzGF2RBmJ0jljQpO76dVtV5qfDkV9ccCDL3vSBwhAmIqC6yb@H7b32AepZWeGaCa@JXVi/1qaCpKOMub52cpewR8DvOMPHTPCB3KKTghkRENItEmz5ucZZKWLrSveUozJr2wLH4JiSe@4KUcn06aAN9@YkkczMCtZwbWsqKphzOmNjfKWwsqcojOEQn3O/LgqHVCZVak2gmjXc4vvI8lH49ZJKwds4iIkUQQ04gAEmiCBxp2kdQ8FGCQbv2hTNIpMny7cxi5yYvxa0kPTb292RLGKPuBGXR6kbeGR2KhveC3tK8uQ/iSIaBpNzgdsuzeU8WBvsLbuUUpuRFoiMpNqb5I5RLEp041tCSgXzYjLPJGqJuC3sRJ@B8zOskYlUW1cKdORBwgSKXG0u0R54ACKkxSZNcHW/OnaAGiNWJZhBJ40ICfIyBkbnjfSTJqgny8urine2UEJf8IjG9nXET/D9mvomqbPp4iCs0PoiFfACqQGSm3YQYrhXpDSHImS3w2pYqMIphh3YG@cMu6NTc/Fv0LPHL1qNMQzwmspJFFzWcIx2kL48Cq6fjdTmRVJY3St1Ips6l@akIN/JshDjHcI1aiAoawvFpW3GQgkjziHf10NfK3PhRCFpBvt7KMxvEkQehJbisM1ER1PmabSQa2pajjI@q7HYWw8gxs5T9khJC70BTlDhwgkVn/Yh4cfv6GaS7Vf4/)

If there are build problems [this](https://github.com/gueststar/Avram/issues/1) may help (Avram is virtual machine for Ursala).
Command line: `fun polyglot -s`.
Compilation is slow (5-7 sec), so I included abstraction test in the test driver.

Three types of Ursala comments are used in the polyglot:

- Line comments starting with `#` on lines 1-4. `#` must be followed by non-alphabetical character.
- `#comment -[ .. ]-` starts on line 5, ends on line 32. This comment must contain only printable ASCII characters and line feed, so Ursala code is placed before emojis.
- Everything after `###` is a comment.

Main code is on line 32:

```
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf
```

`mxf`/`jxf` are for evil.

#### Others

Space in first column in CLIPS code broke Wierd, so I moved CLIPS below 2L. This also required change in Wierd/cockfuck on line 72 to fix CLIPS.

As it [turns out](https://tio.run/##S0xPSfz/P78gNU8hM7cgv6hEwdOfiys3MTNPwVahqDRPQaOgtCS4pEhBySM1JydfRyE8vygnRVFJ8/9/AA), `module x where` is not
required in Agda, removed. Agda is not included in the test driver because of slowness. This is [standalone Agda test](https://tio.run/##zTnbcuPIdc8L5yMOG/ICIAjiQoIXEQRJ3eayI1PWaDx2SIoCSZDiiCI4vIzAoaiyk9TE681L1puttR1bM5ukkgc/bKXyEJe3KlX5gP0I7eNWquYPNqcbvEgazWRmXa7KaXT3ufXpC7rRpxs1Z3D47bd1Zwg29LzOONpxWg2HqzdAHR73uOOjRrsPSg@2Cx2v@9RT172Gy3W6oDQHwytMUL3eUKWF1ctsNczVe3CmLm1frobRShvU0aCvDg6dvqsWkKUMho1OuwZK/ZIy2O8bXJQZ@vZbXk8AkFwiJnpyztQysmDqGYEHPk/UMOmTSXlDeQKuIpSajhl9XNk52tn5sVQWIQ0Cv14kepzsQ9oIqxyvhrXTpKoeHByQA4CSHbWjFamkCJWSCAySYCeT4UgiFY7khSosIAmSaBjSfRXKYEI56ThhOW7kuxmUpCnEQEeUpimMOpgmbFL46j@@@uyrT1j4jMU/ttvt3qDRwOgdwhE8RThqAn0Y/rRxCXcoXms@Feteo91tZUfDJprfEQQzJtzfF3IIIQzsQViQNA0xzozNVF6FEMfbdf4pr@s6P2ahSnHdX/YcFEb4rwNV140ycDzEEqE84Ki6IDNYXc0vbKgkmSKexxiHWIMJHg@N4qVafIUCx9e942O3OwSl5DQrsOfQAHs1GnaHNCg/OqJht07D2hEN2zUa7j2lYa9OA2tZKhsBbNhZNhs0CGYNuw43s6PR6hyjVg6sg@yfBvAu4HO8ZVm8bVdkZTotRfflTGb2WPYCzTAIMGxvZaoo1r4tyyXW7pI964ClVOygNyyNVvctNCtbJcuKVm3bt5XKvl2ivZzQxJ/S1CC4usphimZ9azewuDE3Sac80MDgXlBJaedeYX1zL2JYCm9sFdYjxv0Ha7yOlLkkqTBGyd3NwkbxAWrv3Nss3N@8dedHmw92kD@oVO18Xo7idMhje@1KCZv0fdmWs8PhsPqX1XA0Dax2li3acA2qN2AByfEbtv9AVSxs9L1qmnZwl9Wm4GBUTiEwy/ElviTKOTmndbQnmn6kH217xeVTLPooaPvaI6@vHWqHegOXDWjuA22sjX3t2CvqDURdDNoxom2t6ceLiWLe11paV@vq@hVzr3@Oi9520UODHhYb@tqQ2taamLeKxW001sTqH2Foa5rmYzt97Qk@WkdnsF/VsNMSyjSkNK1c5kpADlz8BEZ1IaoJ0YQgtCtmovd4MjUSj0u90XAAZrpScv32sEIgIlTLJaGS4dVBuaxmev12d0iMOMkAVZhOq9WNwl6hWsWvK8/71oqcl5U8QtaWrVmW4xt2JldeVej0m09EXrVyZTumUDwh4@gbyLNU@R1haRLzUJkTxJOHDx/S@PDkyUmAMSTglR8upDR5qCIrwCgLgaqqN5W/ivivzjhRLJmVyVSSpLKQEYKBEkVwnzgdkehl32iCQSSn2xDTktcHPWZZICZMkGw7YSIjkZIUUUP5rEiZ9Hq9MonWxkN3EK13nMEgmy30@84YqJE4GhHTZjZbJk6/WiYlo0LLmko6AV5fScckIkn7umVhHbQKQ0I2EXzi9QWYTC8HcTK1RAYSDZJEmRLOGpbbkogKkomUPxHBEi2R8pBFy02mNkWZ3gSxkihVpOk04GEqSlZg1ZZw4ODQ@3M9uJv8/3m2H8AAnY8pL9JpAHFTEmtjV4onxJScnoVsCAdWJDEhhiNOBEcolfLhWDgZL@Uq4WiYRtEq25Ub9lwJvR9cyPOll9V5@mLplyya2SW6QQSK83ym7nUHXseNdrwWxNIZuk3TggSBYpwA@EJtazGFl/uPZNP3D@yNglQBaTrBaR0InewK69ewicZ8jX5gQIJMLbsy4Z1phqc1wJTM1Werg9kXhUzdGbhAJmTF6Zf0CpmSlUltCjhKYV1y6/gmzXgmE44HeDKFuB6WIJBoSM1xlLgDp56hn6EMT2evgAMp8WUuW3NbaA9727u8QGXTNEOqgZn//cSm4YdnYIdvgJSRksNyvhROp@n7qDDmaYjLDNwhsM4DUUiwyiGVZq3gB4OgJstd2UG3YhbCG@EA02ncDA24HnS9E0hq0PA6HacPXrMZQuahM4Ca63Zh4HY66O6BNxrCidfvNE7aDTfElY79ZkU5dtrdrFLSE2ZFwXf8yG8Ce6/cwEU43nHckeuejEYn7gLW2wPn0SOnx8BvXjx/dvH8by5efHzx4tnFi89enn/2DOO/Yfw4yD/@fdqk6cvzv/@Xi9@9QOYfMf4B43@@PP/VT4PI6C8x/tcl3pezeEkviBza@ujl@Sefvzz/u19j/O0s/vp6vPj034Pnv2eBoi8uPv2SJjPi2cfY3W@@eE6fT7745g/P6fOv//TNF//wzUf/zJDfBMj//Pb3Qfr1z559/Ve//Ppn569Jn70xPX8L/vmfgfP27XwbO2/Tr3flnH@n9vwpo7GsBecAzrRfXPzq5zhXPw2ov0UKn4XowwVxRRIQHy4JtPCPNxT6xcvzX36@oH5@VfGKDI18iLLfXZF9ePH8pxef//XF899cPP@IrlIlno4UIor@ZuefR0XzLfSoYuJt9FAxUAlBiDNYTpMZE0IM88OcGaNnJCUAOWCerlDPEcqnnIm0fKqiE6mBejqTloGKURqLM6mGTrBGpSYl59JLTcnRmL/imwcNCZ/mAZWx8CVlppgLGjrjy6dXPuq0JJOHFg3HuKwstCgfumFgcpBHMW6AbA@0aEoJ5KzhgW12bsvaKchyEUhlwYY1qphFmskpymjcLvHkj@wNWKMnTcrewBEKjs54njugZ2OZqduBKtgcys@QsRaYYdaoqTMOWXLA2cD8bKbvc8wefWYOKMVpnAswkSHgIUl3HWZnlnCBRiCGeXZ5NOkpmerRcj59YGloZkfmcCDkyOWD1aIKecniFqT8Si2L9lyTyUsZzDbPK6ZkeMXgm4RX2Nz1gnCjlVkLXiu91s259IYa51L@1SIL0eUBkuWrA0ZLXu2UzMk8VhaeVRqWwxytO/yuMGsTq@DG4XgDXB7v8LLnl@0uW7@0ytobFJCZ7rJuZlEMfCrq8AxBT8QXhiVOpK4VdTABFbmfeKur2TM9nuQwZ/QI6g51mVw8FuFUPXT7btRCoNr2RKFrmrPvb@6hbK8IuqFFoaRVJvGkETfjphFLJMykoccT6XjCTMU0XUtopmHo6Xg8nUonp5z9Y/CjsLPzQ2WKhnxFUQ1qEbK6mcyMs1iSsTibOWaBQzieKOgL0haUmS86qXsNl16rTNht2nsIwL3HwXvIQlCmnNdDv6993PP6Q7hTzFBbuOL7o@7Sg8aT@f1hn@hmmjCHW1EGXNntNgLjXBIe7GCye@fW7b1L@d5mYf02l4C14g82rmXmTMmEe5tbewsyGUjnRc2FiZ9s3rt3nZxl1CsOgZmMRKLRKCY0jzBgeXRlf66iR1@/S5GEZiSJHqmOXXSNJ4oybbVrrp7AI02cvM@jRz5oP3VxEKhzPMTTrt9kg85te30X0jo60jA8bA@g7zbQwEkXvK4Ltc7IhVHv9UzMKIui/XbrEKfgibdQGAwGJyeL@4OH88uCxaXBQ6g5Do3vCliDexmGb2YMgzoY7xVJ51V17jYeMY5H9UPA8WgP6e13uwkaF6Xz0zDSKTOVjhmpSCqdipt4mDAjuhHRk6lkWovomp7SEykzrUdS8XQsjksBpWY6yfE439pNVcX1qxPC8na33hk1XGswbLS96KHN8Q232cbxBF9sSMA3FoxRCkgsVdYACxKufuj0w36WGHHQNYjpoBOOOFAHfmtrXdvaImSNEvTmal0jpEEJM6VpyTVCXCZZx@VqYKFDSm0m6BUXIW1KrBe2tqiFR5QwUtQGIUeBJCA6cyKJal1KxGLUABDyeGFOQ@Ne0KIUKzUMCE1bWydkFDQvhQH1CgEVZ43dpAQV0EJbgWQdZYTcmhdCJ4qQ3UBvVtXteX8LBULuBEShQE3cZZ03g059QIkCAyzURwpnLiEtRFp9PD4SUkOUzl9C6ojVxw7yjhE7dlpud@gQMg76QXtCiM@0nfoRIdU5H@vB9ty@7RwOG24rgHE/yOsouoOitj/a3KrdulVrtWr9cWHz1i4T3b1723k0HvVrrdqsYK2K4NFSKDo6Hl8Hl4qqVadzs@gDFHWviarjqstaWHUeY8tm0KIVHVfvUtFdFN30v2JmEOEYlWsU1o4xX3NqgWgOTMRyv1YjGTpl6dJpimziOhGW1dgeNQGg16aik2NfqlX6lfKaohYZpSTFzI1SJJEkq2HMSY7EEMWlAZqgARChTIhUSldyJGmSVSGXU4T39RyQZJqskmQSv/RSZko/cqI0aYp@xM9qyFBViy5ougQxX@w9sw3CSBH8dCJ7rhCs/MXaxZ0Dv9KAUVE4Ku9lZy0mIJaJRO9t2D4miIKQNARBEjJYNkSwLbOm0G6zLs9bTPCbgS1OG1i87w5H/S5omekrNfePVgdDB/e406CGVSAJ3M6QjSo3bAl5PNxEVsM107K/9wr8xfdugpu5FLhgc07oHD/lGu1BD@Jpjp9w08nUsuc1fgDjsSPPDxDwPkBLXuFWBNpxIXbVYy5kC63dwvyaq7CO57aYF/f4lZUVjrf2bBIjxWh1caltq@w/SZn@RKE/HKLlqhWSv9ONtxK18/NfRNh0leu7LcAhzJLZnZSYMumLaMGAl78jYCVcFm1yGXpdSHi6euodb0T/5UE56JB1xrObadiZNEfd@rDtdVe3qe8iOqvBPl2q4BQ@@0G7M0nFFHuHtQ1n8JRNinqR/e3j@K43Q3Ec0Qkcuv5QRE/HZJ4Ovq7e/fR@cj@1v/2g@KC4lddWU6spNujl@TyJ6IIusNeYx62qvbv5fziyVfRATz1TP@vezfCrPSEWF2ILYTnLB6OIOF0aYqmkV6AUq1RKOB0rICGZzRo53UzJ8VU9CRJvG8nowBnzFT6Y2WI8KSHB7ioNnX94FU6uEE/YbzWOT20fnLLrw0HdbrRabYNhqgqwMrWm@NjTkmVNLaD@7ZQ9QTKdBnL20A7MCZYt4YreUmcp/26zMVrlK2eKFTwWTdaLwSCQhEkk/iBr4xzZr@5XeY5PAzHYe5XV4EKyBxD4LOEuC@4gTMP@khFGJyy8oFwrPADTxjM98lRVLUs/NNChSacTqQTP/S8).

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but is the block comment actually a string?

Comment: Close - it is a list of strings, but I don't know how items are separated.

Answer (score 5):

## 173. [Brat](http://brat-lang.org/), 8940 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf*#p 173#*s 
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796loTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where{ fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B 128;}
>g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>data B=B{u::Integer}
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#   print(171)#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rbyNJkiD4OWPvH9wXV1CVjBDJ4ENvUmQmU49KVWWm1JKysqoppjIYDJKRCkawIkiJTKUKM3uH3nks7nZ7ege9PbdT3XN7uAFuPwx294BdzAAH3H5dzI@o@Tg4XP@DPjNzjxcfkrJ7BnuUyPDwh7m5ubm5ubu5e0v3e7/5TQo/7Ni1J13bHbKh6Q9Z27OuTE9jzybsqW7566VVScJYda876pvO0C9LKVZkzHIMqw3vbOhemo71wfTAv8TYwHO7nt5nw54@ZKZv6APTZ@5oOBgNmduZn2yVsf2@@97KYcq@5XQh2tD0Bp45pPA1xl47tt5vtfWpkPWpDAcehPtsz7Q/9j8OmeH2@7rT9iHmBmMvXc83Mb5h@r6LyTcZG@@bxhTQLYiqe5b7ov7q86mgbcY@BxT1gW2Omd7yh55uDC3XQZoU2Omr16fHUymKRfbV2cHBtG@JfZlzHXYwMi6ng1bZa8/XbX0a/hqrj4bu4XDaf53Vu6ajs5K2rZWmAzfYM09PJqHqPPbc9shAUg97JmCA1dOxbNOXDIheYwPBFBo6WIp5pt7m0aSO6zFMwvqXNrOYMRiwlq33NIPZFsQ9KGwxE2uTfYBwu@ez8aDPfKsPUHy3b8aL6zPHNNvMH5iG1bEMwoCZ46Hp@ICprzELyHNt2TZrmzYkiNAysgCMjfyYF0dCk9quxOBjDKYKEb4tmxDHMQNCmAOobCSEi7wBVAnoce3pgwEgCXQ8BcSHVh9Y2RqmfWbqvoWNBZL4ptMmGg7CZuQy3YmXkl1ZUJmA78gj2L7pYUVoBJf1TM8EkHrIyMq1Zw2BBEjiOjs2dY@deaapJptUIkvIzMUchlgQjapwZye9f3SQhqrkKTR9MJRS3urZj76QdKZV2fJFBb5VWa5I@6/22M3yObp5C4LqHniKrrLqd8zPn5@b8B0XW/mudysBVAmoYrO8Oxjm9dwAEMwNAcG8jk505a5K2sCOZcx2puoixmA8Vhtqgx067KsslcwYeR5KiYio@iUU2nadLtATCuuNHKSHwzYKUAWGC408y8wroBq0Kqoj95oofNazoNJ8rJJYI@CyjggK0g54T1A0yNd37RHFg5T@EBkQqAJJEeJhh33FOrplYxIIR1Aca8/0R/YQ04ycNtY8yDKzrbEADcNtY6S@ewXZ6QCUPKA99WOtkJCCyFARLhUVg374F3/W7nYBTt0wXK8t2PUr1nYNkso6IQuijiHDuo5uE1oQL4u58@SQwZVuW219iNk7E5EFIUG5Xrsju81cyNC7tqBp9fQraI6djmkMTc7kXJBnWV@/5LLD4pwLBe/rLahYyoDypmLn2NNdqCXDlFLEM7n@aNjZYrnBPkv7@bfKk7LyZOncBORUTV1Zzue7FWA4bYW84C19F@d8VU/IOn@o@67VlgaTYc91SixnMNmougPTUdIJGOls2mulVQ1lmqJWrKqhdSynraR3gBdrkHFarRhVo2GVm5Wp5PEsAcw1gsHmaiqGKksgcqhRXOX7uuVogwn7KidcsTDXv0CSY7AW80bCTPtdcY8UdWTIly4yCMghzbdNc6AUtKKKYgLjzS03Bswr6RQMUeCy1cykU@lMvOgEAUqaKCg21jPLRbFlD3rYhwFRHH8A4ttD3jV04B4fpfgQtIksaxFfk@gHyUIy8dpMeyZrgSAN@IiaJG9ymD6HglJAiJpQsiWb7VhDBiEAbXnoz0hj272GDAkn7LtAdDiYqd6FqoHEvCB1XhCeE/kki3TpgEBBaC2TbeVaFjQCbG4g0wXPx8oG0VdLPA5A440kJnv6@gSgGLwvjBoMszrQlvogHrwJM0yUOSB8TN6hYCYjan8@6E@oSRVypfX1ZBubaWJDL1/P/RiE9If8nS0JC19PqAjQ83TMa2brTnekd1GFcyCJbhjmYCgEFZTEH4Iomu5vyDMnOk/N70nLT6fzpk5EdKuxPFDI89oTXaGO0kUocTkbhCnThRrK2pYHYsmeTOcOEa6mMpffYZQEAu/kBSgEGgAwmTk2jdEQpBow8HXPMnrAs4idw@Ui74SmsweveO4g2XOdMGtEplh7XJK0fOiFaCwEkcManYUDnSuCqiU8qPLjHndD1v3@HMBuiCJ0BDFfLa9rwHv3wOy7jjsHKBAyBItRkiG8HkATO0UtEDquQO2ixhqqhmEVQZ2B1ICWD/zXGw4Hfhn6CWvYG7U04JT8mTc5HB45yCz5oTexhi53t2y3BWLZh/aZD3LIG6OWNZ4qEPmFdfjel65AAev4rAo997cj4Dol3fFBYJL/LkaOBckkuAkE/5UhIkXSgFBKxydRfABC5XTiGIqsUVPSoNHJWSZjw5VVcGCqkC67bh@lEHtDigFqeqDSW04HpJWQ@STy9bldXSj7Sa9Lp7X3ruUoN@mlpaV0OV0Dyb609ARcO@h6gq4MuJ6QK0cujKehi1JkyYWhDUqBfs30bSOAPFabWG1j7JU@WANFb5TLq82s3iiKZwmfKog6kGwQO4cPgJNWq1V0qqpcu4aCaq1OsvS7KJ1PDc8aCCJ8oV/p/F1QYZXIYPUHrocKbAU72btp0q960AuC0mr0FC993iicN89vztuZ89t0FlOrFb3agkJBfkpf63ruCLpLtbFWzhWbqtpYhU6yVU0X0iuKspWzISNdVT/bUjM6p7aSNkFqK@fnaSCqoE/D6HkEb5wtqWpIKsADO2bQCZW0drMF@bfUpppJQ1o1nYUhRjWdBsoYSASfCo2cSQQ6AAbcPX2RGEX2L0E8MsO3UZfIeVydgNf8Cvds0yNUmcrskFROB/pLQAG6y3Y4tHFcJ@eMSAEm7dSNZ0SDMIxBfth5oGC0EnEQcMcag4YPDXcSaDLYAaMyswvDPNc2tTekW8gMOJ9he9XmqjPHvF/QDD@qRFBcwDmwdQNaZhLcuczOASAwaj4/P0StzACe1nVoWHJfGaFnMHQH6de2SO0eWX4PyQuqEY4FvA5QFXVu6NxNotohM6DT7gKlzbE15Eo4MMIpJnmu@4qKal@dq02orWGXj0gFQ3bqj10DBiwmdP0Yykd/bN@5sjzXQSJr@wAaOLaCdTAFfB55gY3q9cPS3mL6zgMOFJvxLsZoG4c6TVzDN1jecW2367IViICsqWmcsQ8dA1AApW0I40PmWx@IQPWuCyOXJA@a2F/7qOQVN1ZD9VnHmHmKr70HYcHmFzqKsKDMp4c/3gcRX1wvFAD/4K1An7CQMSjTZURPg0URRLOFpn/WG5mSafRcJp9DB1mqsXzbvMpjc5OhJ@qBppcDbcr0SJcIk4nZLWnojkApaZu21beGhzQ3YzvY80a9ShC6C@wVATi2zKEk1OWoM8ZpmkhQOl0ef3@M8tSXTHqyV0d7@xfH9bPnVTk/8r28bbWg/trmRR/0Jtv0ZcZS7MSE1CLBh0v7xHWHVaoSnBGa/aQwUhD/xd7Fi8NnJ/WTb3g2lM63@iNbx8x4/FN6D9gkNp3U8dx@qCP6grbLq0hNMzHDiAMmEbqGoSMxvxjz30D/Ps4ZaobUNQyWc/lr6CkibmJEnEfUjMFA6mYyGJPmFUNPEXOLQOLcoua1As9t9AxnFWNqeBzcvPDFiQTkm2LhFoH7zsgfxEp2UyyS/9Ww08F@JPQukfdlDsCAAhl6r5I3n5VMZBWQZSZobuQQ3hrB47OZc@HNBM2NHMJb5/BwFnQ@uKmQeVFDYBsEDGdN58KaCpgTkbPlGcjoFy7I4xeWTzPfcT6Vwo7/XJID7SWhpMhRSCmaRWC5q/nTH3IcEDUZYPJLF5XmyHUBQ/11hBKC6F/asyk70HXRTyLqDFKzIbyp9lsd@pkToSxG1iB3cH4XqfIFzg7i4N8FRcK8pmg0RiBgQC3L0fMn9MDRwjx8kuOeBDItszOCPjYPShy674mW296imJ1Wy1oUFeiCqAfPOdG8UWse2WDM0psZGrME4Ycjb2ibbfH8r7/XhgqYrZ6ePiG9InRcAN2INzoLa0skxRf6mV@zFOf9yLZ0IgO57gNp6DgbqduhYz5o7CJYLtfTvT5236JygTnxB0TQHXzGMfdMe9Q2g@f8TIjEyQE4T@1YfSoRPFH/pPHEguRT0wc8PWlwtqu3CQrXsywzqm1eL@aYaxwx3QSk/APwDEb5LJpWh@HscMR/cSb9vnq1BvidT5VykskK63qraOZdX29Z5h184OmXo7abG1x2qdCI2sYibueNCAeluY6tX3LnBTrnE4AX0bO6XRiMi@eiaNc90KP8AWhi@Wt63MEqQT/HSBnR74Lp2fx3UZRgnTJ0LKaTZdPPpzAksYgBrQZJi2tcuRiZrCnC2nprgsPJ3qdzFmZICgQInqqRyRRWsQsL50aj1bTBYHF67Pco/fb2/NR84Y0AGG6nY5r3tWbokay@budK7ZhzoXAOJjsi15yopODnDFv3gUmGgszmFVQL/dzFuNjJGMgukesOto3QCaa@F82iRmkGluHalj/gLUm8LJKS0/NPERhcXqWfKCm@zdK3DaMY7MBzoWt@Q3eNIc5kLuCjBwguPomI07QxxtDcRbQz3Gv8LlQdeu6VyX/nd2Yf5mL1ABGUs4kzLGNO8rZxH7viWhj9zKfi5VyshoY917/MXrqu1zMdn5W0QjDrggsRum3zWc2zw6PFPO1btuvDAAh/76IFDHR8n//O5@Y42SzdydHcUtw9P5lAasA0MRRfUJm63XXtja1uXoefhTU@8joo2cXzoRItlEjF4r0SKVR8XKcongtF@SX838cMNH/l4UR1zHlHPzpPfIkJzsUFhOEBrj7NL9xBYYtSank@Gl1UAZ7Ru9YnwfO36C0WUTfoLQYTUptBr8ME21vgGHpclf5tclu7O7f2w2TSDNjN@woRq9xL2wQJTb8zVcpKheInpigWCg@XUB17ZI7MuRLjqPXeRDuhO2TFw5EqiGIsi5mZPBAP52XCWB/EoPBBWGP/jW93ChjdtqCR36u9zJV3A9C1BziOPgbHMTpmE3ad0SBRuTHanYyck7sp1xsELdttJ5DEkE@VSFv360gJddw36btIdd/vuzD0dfugMzgPqH8BlKa6@G8CMPlEkN9bOC3o3Qm3zMIVLdBXQf@AWrUu/RzOLT5M8JQWjdkp8vY2jMocczjB30XUnidIW65rf0rtgDxtW6iWgbKJJmv31dKMriMWN1k0O@HjTEers2hegvc1YgAJ1MPB8sKKPoYiDalzeEgtz8xl3tFrxWY27xtHQo9Nkz@@ZwTuRfieYOMualva5p0Ic3XUbZm2zh/jjbW74G1rqw9RiQaBnkuT2zghzqfAowWZ1JQIGkyAWFY75xs9s2/S6x1Kvt5@P/KDx8JIYxe/c4K1PM3@Lkg3sKDNO/ibmG6PaUVD1zH9/FD3uiYOT2xcBRG@i@RsMKk8l7iHfb1rHtzLXNHsA1q@0CpjzDl/HqLMF6MNSHaPJOEjP9e5NCd@8JyvH08MqM9R/05o89q5gZOc9zZsLT93Lv0etc/puT2nZ/Y8ahzh26LmARw55EbCdxUC8O/p/iWa@pBMioZ1PT9OXdu17YdQF2Uil5CuO3/@dR9ta9uQ9JPgTvQWBIjHvVN10HUTkagPX9R2euYIeijfHboDM0dvi6LaOKnDf@dPKR8epX32xjK9Nl/mxBk@fWi1bJNdW4DCez@@XDh/wqhluzpak92hxANlgudDpqAM17uvV@jq7nAwoMfFwB759EMzubnO/CnKMjsgRB/CC9aQLzBzjjW7bsvoWfdVXsvUh451mRetX7zO5/KkLKaCWyy3h96abQGpvImGPFCNh5/i43B@u7deCBP/O/WR3ZHnTe6XDcnF03BWla8FoGPR/ItYFJsTTD0/WlEE1gJ3LEiINbSFDEW6NOrNObMAyklx4WxQwuJDkMBeXR3eQyXDNS7vVScWzk@K9VYklWHFVoXBf3oS4240ngvxBoND5fmo66v3xZ@gqrVn9fkOAN2ObJ3uSVnvcs7BhSTfdq9jE80gEnRHPOZyXunF/e2JVkPW71wYKbPii4v60eH9wAzbGvj8l@U6pbkqxOya6rwcv8EqvJsyp9ASOg8fPPRdD81jQdvIGZ7pGzgJjoKaC1Aunhy3CwI7Z7MochB3bllm13PnqTHJzjD39Suzq6O1zQsLDW9sf7Z/BMjTS7sPAfyjke5bPxq5Q3MuzOkl3hmQfIX3hLYghMaqflbsnQA/yxOW8n64HSVF5ixkuhqYMrIUGtSOsKkNXU9jFE9R9ExGVSWeCCctuw5EC2LRhgA0FuZ7DXxmW/6Q4lod1miw5ZtxuVAu3rIqk8syazY5VDJb3R8PyJL/hCdtLOvN6nI6l0svp8@dMiukKapp@@b8qHoiXseiB8czKjpzdG6shO6gpBVuBO33aIMBdEtt6N5ew6CIRJzrcVNebid@hquf/@Uv22LfBajAPutb0BaAELhXyO2bPff6Cc9X5F4fDHTct4EwrnvYd2Luud0686@xH@TbLdxr9vrgbEsYcYsdTfByjAI7hgWvVByPoQXXkFcax6btmrwdiYzDVEGhDNce9R1QPNrDnq9B2yPjrJEXGaWAC6M5Qw@1r3aWHbK2iWtMZHNHAw7bdS/J@hUx@S9/yU3XyfJOWEQF2dOWlViOaGBXJHtxw3BHgHUA5IPpuSKKgkQGzh7hcB6kgMn9VbRHI5t64MRcYFGO2XCr8t36KcvtszRuuUI71YrVUZbrJ59/1Sg0q9@xft78r7@XV28E3eTPctsbvpxlQZTKLfJVPHgdgqPQNJOXx7IoFm7uob0sIVOJDYQKuqm6AgvxPu0LIr4zr8lCnOyaHGy4uOEGuhEfVN6hSqB5o6kuKyM@cMydDtk67kuDsZgOLr6TiOzt0NoZkyyP2UfWQ17JGWgDBm@cIDYa2PerzwLbgdW4hUd@z2yNaFnzqqSVVqtUnOWL6k6NXJ7ZdnGjS@Pt@bhUyJ2PN/ebeT8gzvn5@LNC6Wugngs67fLjPDag/Vd7N8tarfDxo69PmCzfpivcZAVa@fLN8eHx/ulZ/ez1KVDzlhc2deB6fT2SFMgLZNLWc23aQQRk8SzTv196hBIkfIPoisKWdbaD@x5VVYrbc1FUQWo5Jy9zZxgFBnfx1Pckn5feN2PhsxGEZOpYTEhRdkyMJHgm7cclaDbgLawXbO6ggocUQYOgOaKQaCSzKlApB1R6II3YbCl5DT4hD6jG@wl1N4x5IIBWUYzZCEikMC8sLw/nhZtb@Nt/gBIPoF/7XUtMMO4sMca4q8QQMUpGKQ7qhy9en@wnEwE7RdtFYQDt4SbkDrUtvvGMc5cr9jgFkonGnr7Y0xDKVp9dWT6NTZHfOtgz2CBcsDmSdYOP0oVbQLO67YMkb7dBNLUmQ5RsINI1slTj5mo5h8kpIJYWdrRZJksY16/O7nkByXVtgBR7xxMvUzyC7EtzNuedm/kf/sWf8Q1550Nw/6FwjwvP4O2PxVsH3P88CCkW4e1fhm8lePspf3ubR1LO7kLipQmJiAT86vCY@TR8RhL19XGs9Ni3Yd9pOTCAs/pA6ysiHUbnxYooE8FRGl8B5aG6gOwopFEuU36m11RwD0k5n0dVBOc8NbKpMsd88ExbSr4d4VZK6EryG@sba0UYPZq5qwAgmYV30YiHA1TVMnCldGUNqu9aBtvZ2WGyb@i2Wd2ocJLnl/W3q/K7ENFliCtxraXBIA0kiVJAWE0kU5b1TFHFpNg408U0a1ZAIeE1CH2aQg6IoqK3E1gWQ6fpClIBezjmeEiCfxJoY6AKOWTYavINtQGgHADisHHD3zSXR2Y5aMUY43stXg3yG4x2itHK8jwma7xl58Nzpyk2fjJgmF/OYTkH3H80ZzdoyD312W2IyvQmQiwNe3rquGi@dQDYMqWUL63mixtqrE3JAhTgiy3oI4CENgNt0DCt9@7Ar@/uH35xdHw6s52OYqano6VZuraTOc9p2UYzdKSnuD4g6rOD/OnLZwcBKeNYRasfGCNaAplGc15u05guyP0Nt4eazZsCZjIqFh4KmIbwuQNaJZyFHoXmYxF3ub3GTK6KenPbaO7Uzp3UTPYf520xTmkryFzgOvdpg3GazZE5h4GV1xkeS@FrgTlwSY420IcmwPw98l68IS485CLaFRfYk0lk8B/a@0vaAkszKLuW51nRljCOWIAvyJoA1SKiGmVoSDMrWHFsmCjL7HkcwhY6JNIRH8jSTl/dgTGMZxk8tk8Cmg93aXsqDHgOh9EYCcZdOG1DQ8EJDXtAVIQTR22LRte6F5ilhyGnZt/KnQX4oOCIdrmJ7V0woO/ZVquiVxtjFhpT37XZS/MHtjVUcOfZWMPhJJRGUbEAxR3cujVWd7abYpccCzazZWg/3PEI6HXsDlg0hN8zA9cJjOLY3giAAxuY7ItRH@J16HFiYi9hslduDhIDHdMBEg3cASbKoPXb65C71jPHbasLPY2iZkEkfVYsRjvpdNwK5qRBDnNSfY5mPXHCfNLuvxjF9IauWU7bHCu4aaXcROqAf/r6zVValWd4gLYgih157em9iIGw0Iei1Ub7@KYEwvZ2KAiSbWd7W@v5Ehq7wwgEcjwdei/ACX2o0unrA6aMaDOnzzRGr8q54mT9oaeyXA37s2vmsEyGxi7woACNUcoOuSwb584VPPtAyVehntHXd9r4@GANWKOoaU1wUyYqW8bZh11QN3DcrkqgmkKSMoGFDhj@yojRNYzSECP@XKZsJdqOBbHmBlND7vaoAQItqNSs9jja/RNrgZyq29tlURtJcbjNgC125kgMADtHzAW6KdBXmCsD1VCIQaxdGJRaIFCefmk6DrRXBXimD62T6SNgMk/NBucBZaMzHSiHFEfxubB/BkSTZz3sp29sF/SZ5XyFRsCVW@j3351jx98RXf8k/9/ntXzlRlm2q5M8KGNqTVnuVYuZ1ZVMZtlZUZYdVEceP8aB8@0yaDsXmqzJY4iUW7bVCvAzaEfVZaeyrO8oy@1qaYVSwGsmo95Agu/8vHazrN/mlx@DNpEFH4@3TmXZp22YBU0r3gJ@2EKW81ngmRvcjkin/GD2y1YmgzhoyxeIwHf589MM9Svnp3kao1eEkpvv9gMxktRVwpqYOZ2IE1B4l0OJvo4SXaxxXwSR4yc9zAm7U7v@Ei2CGK1emL4f569kyMMFixBoKJyEkFH4Plgg4FgBIuJrVldVECa/@U2quAGjvicbq4qbebJeqGTS68VKOsVST@X8iuzJN@d7uStm5tKNjr6ufds8vjw@/lo9V9g2S6d2j@TimvyWbZdW8lIqv1L4uJnPv3v3DtRh1qhpNa2pNnLpZkPhA7pNVtvcXMlubK1kn6YvohHkJlOVUkmFSjtn6@x8U9dXMmulp04FQrbxs8qK4MTfLfgW2fo628fP3/7Hv/353/6M/n5O37@2LGvgt9vwdXvskn2Az2WH4T@5P7Rjbh3drc4HBcYZoH5WqWkUj9Pp9dX06VvccP1kCf7oHz7hK/4ukY/wpiiznyUpVTNSH1LFYjE1ob8LdBfHscFzjl7Giz75YrF0zqTUClvdWHoKVDVBiOKnXH4awsjLm1uy65JHD3JYZ26KtY9iuYxz@JFSwZEluYbeabJhHf/YWQv/Tob4l/vqEv9ODPx7dol/L1v4d3yKfwMf/37Uoz8P/547@Nf6Fv9efMC/M@PMENhvVbMMkP@uWuVIM4H89Ge@t6ZdBC6E8m7nXfV3@7BP@QykFAz6UrVaM5O7vW1obzOVivgHcVkJ3/DDXYBv8zaX23lby2QahHejJgqwk2vWeGnoV7t4uwNgMzuNnR3tolYb13LNt7UGlvIGfwz/Fh8lGZrg@Qo6q@OdEw5yL4CJ7YLhH31e8Fwaxy9glHOWLe3kUqWD@m62dPr6WaoIb@vRKwau4uvJfn3v6DXEPn6xXz/d//zwq/3Xx@DvNy9qT59mNOCZp4BwrdmQUuPPMrVMdTgcXvz4YkXDDnKb95PbIQ5Tn4s5Lv4qpfZq49f53A4g/eJiGwt4QrnlgBrNj4yDlVKNVEPJPMk8KdiFq0Lxsnj50j2K/o@OxhBgjQvvXa/QK/SKbWhbrGC@LkwKk3Gh7x4V2@A04a/QB6dV6IwL3YJTcIrFyTgBavF//8gdvjxyAZoLKYfjwhABA6S1o42jpwxeu0dHLwFsB1B4D39WoVAYA67jwhX8F@wifd5eFKDgKm5PhrdC4fxcajD5nQmyUiumtUJa20inreb6xuDb85vb0sa3DdLt1rebDdyK3pRZNn1x3kg3K6m8f36e53JdLq3JFdqrfnt7cbFXP6tfXORxSmy8s5x5msk9hU@1ltkRjyepdq3y5LycQyYM2DGV33lyXlvNoXsjA1VQAr@dfOYTPxFIeNaWzqW0cv3mzRv8vrm@uuYucnC/8zdhKP68yYMXd6EXfDBqfl76pGM8y3eK0lhv3txC/3aerqRFD6gwOvdBLp6PSx1WknGUoWyroGQUV1GV3Vhnaq22sQ4eG1tqTingKIQnOZcHg8G5rNG8i0amsNVq3fP0CY61lDUAomyvV6vnsu5dnMuNUhPTrue2N5jr5bZXVVlV3xZ3diAPzKKkgrecHsuul2Y3t/E/5eZ2R6GPin@qip4q8A09a6oCEdR1eBvfKGxH2VHQD7ww3c1tDZ0U7wZcDUVtqre33A9@FXWHQ62pQDgGCsY/0j90PP//@X/5mvmgp9ymUHN22Nq6qrQmprq2oWxltsVfdQkIq8ir6VVUidJ6utF4urK6srnWeNJc0Vbwq@yc15pzumcVFCVoykHbqxZTWLEoz7TKiVwsyWl0p1IVQ5x0YbtdtrpdwSOiMKEMH3RJaQYVWtsJWTjqudUa1j@jGmVqk6m3N8DWPBC0a0UsUJ2fjwuFIJHKKq3q8k1Kv62kMBd2KwdJRAuhPJR0hVYx5Rt5WfcaxaZ8Ky/ftG5xKLJSVEkLXV@rVFbWuHtZUYrbG6XtUmlzY2OruLkFyslGoZBnxeJWaW1rdX17bW1ja30D5JuqVijDleKKgFMAOMK5VamYvm5UUHBVUoCHosCgD4ifOpeqLbML2QOBBvE2nVlfX1/Kl@Ax/mxjvzRe2lmhT21l7mertJVZyTxtrGxvYyU2yfPjklTBRUW@ginnZC4a2NY2YZLC5Q@@7rB8DCqJ@FvZW@GuIn73l3xpwBwY1G4WWNu1cUOj2@ksgWdP91nLNGH0Ztp2cJQKDDDt9rXVNpekRn/cadKm8WquUdxYb@aAMd6POytQ0uLmamrFJ66QfBM@/WPdHJnm9Wh0bYafXcvX37/XB/QZd3745U9@@OX/@MOvfvrDr37yw69@/uvvf/4T@P4lfH/Knz/9d9vr@Pvr7//l//bDn/8KPP8avv8Zvv/p19//69/jX3r/G/j@XzG/vxHfWDz@lQDWH//6@5/9xa@//@e/gO@/Ed9fTH9/@NN/z///b/GHzl/98Kd/gz/i5Sc/heL@/V/9Ev9/9ld//59/if//@//693/1r/7@j/8tOf6MO/6ff/Pv@O/f/f5P/u6f/snf/f73C35/cufv9w/w//4fwefheD4EzkPK9ak@3/9W@Pwu1IhyAR4ATvujH/71HwCv/il/@2fwBv9h0B@GL4kQ/vKH0QtA@F/mJPqjX3//J38Rvv1BMmIiDID8IYT9eSLsD3/45e/98Bf/ww@//LMffvnHKJpya9vZejZXvHsEkYKI6w@IhxE3HhIPIvIoS2xJKtETf4QnWyLXeEVaX8WBVo5/Mtzz4zJqnuz8o7QO75mPeTwsh@U/itBz3IJUhNDVNQotgCJdwNB1fA1CY6jgyvWTpwn9niOy8hG0YlBx87HYPOITjqjwz3xMyHdMSeFLIeLwjTJbCtMvzSHME/YUgqH7pB50B3/xBXyewahPDP6qtS1WlbJsq4pniWDEKrxTODrpHTpbPGq6Ku2xZzhcRe89oBAfo7Ox9I69Q2zRv8ajspoE4d@BxzMOhqAhqO8k8Mpwnz14fifijyWCh/9CfUU3foMA@Mkw7gev2P0QHPEj8Rg8mAWPODVxqI3xMN0Y/1kESMDJSECITDY@OAuzyEReUviamcklxGcqLBOFMdGLJkBl2AzAuwIT3tJ0QjYXisBgYehUMYPQOTkGoanZJGFQnECZTJJgmDJZqIyUQRu5FZHpSmaFTGJWPvUjcKIM5pLjjk@c3itRyeNwI@wjqIQvT5ChuFHeBFHhyhWtKbDixloIWJUUOlINVFOc3zAHoN1JL/3uM3esFLKynC1uzJ9EUHE2BOJ@45bL1e@Ka5sSPOl9hKe7iXPGgLfxyG5tBz6Ah1S7yaEQkGqn@2cQdnbEiqWCxhqF5s3aZmltfW29tLqxsb5ZKq5tbK9trG@tFoqFjcJ6qVQEHXZ7a3vzVqp9zcYaOz7@UQ7c41wuX0KArFpc36xMqpCQvKQaaXRck5zc5ECJRATOSY29QQMGnMq5oWm@R/Bh0iOJPQIv@ABgnMdlYv3s8KgiVlnQ1i7U1fmSi1xc35ZJtc/lfOncdNocuDSIfaQzPKz1FQADajjsBZreDV125rp0RN0z01gQY7fHj1vf9Vzf/x3iPNOdSx60Z@GRLMYwDHqu48Zsv28NewtivB700RLa9P7RIOz3W4AgzoDyCM/gx7Ndd16ETfb6eEEpX4YG1rhAQxbWEP3k8PPnZ7Hn2X5997m0wZ4dvdqbeqyLSOvsxf7BWfi6yUODpOshiG/2X7yYfhUPHNAssfXNbFbTNPjBZ5Y@9NSW3wZRitpivULeKJQ25WL2YmLCqOYml7vtWi2zuAFD2DX5cQoGU3jU3yk/zHDotNm4Q2y/vVnc3N6w3TNDeonGKttFbmVs@WhOCaCuHbJmbeE5yaPBYk94oBc6PavbA/Fx7YYRfN@/vg5njt4E00ThdNEb1tJ1/H7qB3Iw45/h3R5Dngf5zYTYs9Gl5zBO7ON5gLgHaohLJFaHFSQNZUWptL21vrW9WtrKbm1vra3DiHA9WyxlYVi9uV3IFgvFrSIMpreL2a217dU1kEoQur69KaWg7VudfB5kb1GW6Wk5Bp7AtINHWblaryal2mYHmZWNlbbKUu3QY7TF5NWt8wKDhLKEFnAr46pcWkPbwNUiK8qSrDODpQ4OdgsHB7L8DF9w1nK3IMttfFnfKhQ2n8mySSG7IDlLkKiHb/sbOL0pyxa@7NYPDhDCe3wpbSEMWb7kIfzFDl42IZqDL6urCIDJ8rchuAIAdzlGW5RqyF8KhWe7sjzi6G3BH8Sr87c1QnYfXzAAEx3wkF0Ik@XPg0SgAMvyCY8nsnoelLdel@VD/lKvI4gvqPDrvFBf4kudPpDIgzfgXFnugqPrmaYjyy1wIv/KsgEuY6KDXx9cuOvTGeqyPOHlwJLI8phi68alLF8E/pAP4PP8ud4bts0u/0w8/jQg6BCCrPFo/6D1@eetbrflTer7n59Q0BdfPNffT0Zeq9sSCVsX8HExFQRd9ifTHxODLi50e37QlxDkTAVdTC5MwvBC/xYwE58uZtS/@AKDvoCgeYtaAiB8@hC5hZ9nfXg@01s8KPhQED3HrZZcQZbFptNRiHH1LD3o@En1hqFtgq/oT0hmlVFeuR3QLUZbam79yWhL3tiUyyvwlJ/Iq@CEpsEK6QJjcvpcltXGdvOJvLkul9NPnuTSj4tPmLy5LZflzU3oddXKLYo7Rb3pKOPsuFoAj3x@Bxs0NkF4gh4gevEzczzUnpu4KG7kcm8Sn52dNxAPd/vgDoRXoz6MD65RcbmhQzIDM8iL6jNW3CxUHNxrY/LX0lYF1JButYHRP@LPTk5@U3sjN1k8l/XNAuDw2jFKmzs7jeuPTanW1oc6DIOe3YzKZZHDbVxrWbZ1f7hc3CyVG6PlRq7YXFoqfOzuyD@uEexbKSwkl16h/IFA6HMYfHM5CcMHVUF1mSl4ki@uotGiu5JOb5bSaTVdgbRLMtBTkJMW2rDaAqrLIPeA6tslSO6ZwxH0ugUo@HTO3mUZiOih1QXlUGbyBqhH4I3HI89@nsLgOlteaa3v1P7JzOe/@yfzPvN98SNxZW@jKKVupTaeGrW2LaVupNub251akOOXbDLRM8EAlj1mrJtZlpbTWPD0anLEVq/Wuyf1YIK2viulcqvumptaXl6WUjtnNXlVPtIuwjWZWp7W@s5xIRAXzbTzi52lzG@1YJPTak@DdU5APS95Jm5BaOOtM3zdZGsdK6LL/FTmt/xAJlIVYEoVnOyWUygBDNsd4aL1zjkv0M53KVpXYcc3nZFDNmjll6gLK3qZax2NJjTD715Z9s3Waq5GphMKcNjtLXGFcUTr2lLKcYUTCAmjkCE0RgVU53VZDCVMNjjdfrv5duvty9dHr48O2NNCeasMw/Jz4JFsMV1MQxU@hY7WOtmXUoOP7nrxO@eLSqo8SK@upVfDKjuvpjh9wI1MrzQaxSZrrDabDWC0JlPhtVotPSmub2XWysVNpqZquEektImURhc08NxqqinArG2q4Kbp8VIxVcungrajFDeLasqXUlsv3@GMSXAdilUiVz7P2PLtzi38125ZY2fnFodA@HsrnhDGw@kfcQ9e6BF9EvGiOFH4b8di2kWq@V1uh//v4M/uES@ZvLEuq6l31RpU/NuLtxcpKbXN5BLVVSYvhjTQbrqoTK049Gf6b1d8@Is8VkA7XAnfzJ0Vn63XijBMNVfy@fy5@qMSaFrb2xtbGynpN0CuO@xLITQ0uOqYMNQAAT3H4qruWS91tEZzQqsrcLwcfcBzr58GN94EShlDrQxNClEti/sJTS3mRRdFJf0mfh73v6CvJKHLoovRWIeYDleVhrSPga3g7nTc5qdKN9IjgDUyhrR1Bn4qkvQI93DgqxLEy7LH/lDFua@CKj16JIStP9T84QUCx0TCM1esSNANAHn0dttndPI8LobyvYE67ohwB/wYF3vCeCKfmgXXMGlbH@YbQ3iFdTgWUJoVRjkS5lg4nv0jHq016iAqB4cv9iENDI47ZPskUsteC@9loOItdVQW9hlAAzycvCooRdExIoADT65AqH3cgGgoFDPDihjeIRsqiJVlxSxhkmUdkbCBr01IjuA7IMN8AMxzV3gJ2MqFyFaUQeBDhQASYumo60OH7nWNrKg9POK00VTZTbDNScFQtsNK0T4sAQsqg9@lRgmNflucMV@NyEzQis0sVG2Fb5dRwnjCJyLUrbQyzPYrvKoGFelLxQA9x/WUynf9x4@Nt4NGv1lR@9UhPjOZPnTHl4rFo6wMq/0qsMegYTUrw0YmYzWrffVLBd/xKgfsu4W25quibFBypwq4oE2ar2Y/NJzcd04ze9BwMoDyKLvy4@qHrF4toJ6VtarFrJ39tloU5YA8h9UPGaei78AX7QgTW5FAA8nolYQXJrlU7OqHht5Exc2GhJnMARQG8PQbdibTVCFzGwJnE1bsx4/1jF0bV@xcTsVYb1efHDSG4GhmqvheVvSd8ZMPjRGkLyvwrEI2tgrIQzpB69sQd8CvAjTmdRqhznEkvXIM6PWr1ZUfP1n58Up1aelDY5zrN7Oc/OVCxA2I/BiRr8S2eikrP1bZFElofViRP7PKn2kgHOWslckAkbODWEqO4cqPIWSQyQRY36K8pBueAhtV5DCxPYkf606HJ5PJOZ2t79MVFcM2btSEtHXfsCwRne@wHVgwwtfxhIIs3d@gUwwME1fOYeD5@MkTKcha7IiBnFG4tEym40wBXTzk4UI1XV/ID2O4T77OE8OBzA1HyHSXAIzFVzdizZVEEzU43zMaGAXFwE3htsIlFt8HBcKGpAfEIemB8XIoRZBIQk6ImFURCLUVVBCkQjnR4QeJ0JEJKJ9Qjw5bPogQjgY05jloWNn3VZJNwE8WuJi1Q/mBA5qK9AgKgThgGawmq4EgY48fM/G6U4VRxib2BRgN473PFDHSDKaQ@QMwBRiI5XvgUZSHlAng9ghDcJ9fIqO13y0jsU1XgQSZ91m@W1ej3brKyPH5JnWkm8rRwLp49Oh9promEIJ/GoZAegi7/U1KdPdltnv08vj12f7Jy/op/MLQcit@RUtw/dnM5UcDvNSoZTm0V83QT4rmN18YjCk41sKTkPF2wzb74vULViq92sviOYZA@hSfzoYOtRxCMn06J97XXK@bv7YurXzyWla8iI62xdElsLngLhdEhzpnO9o6H@2c93GaDjpzcfha4tqUvun74k6nXHA/Jh19Q4cI9HEvPLRCcQcU7TgIjKbJRB@NI7K08cOzuhZdetjjABLp6TaMIU9O7UPCu5torAocLW1vFQplVsiioxg4SoFjNXCsBY71wLERODYDx1bg2BaOYgC5yCHD2Hp1dSNybkbOrci5HTrXCpEzgrBWipyrkXMtcq5Hzii3tTC3jS2Cy1IBNanpmh6GFde2gjCaPRiS5zqAKU57rgGipZmYkHxtxhPy20p6bm4XREaH@SOMVCptRO8gfYK4VYVjleV4ZHnO/E14Ql8l8UEdMey@54FU2h/jZXXAdGqZ4VZgScJzUAzb1EEZMIegpVQPgP9NtcyPyPAm5Wg7MEKoFsN3SI53pUCaIt23yNlnTnBpXjCHVpoLjR/KwkLCxPZSCyQ5luVET8shriX84lCXUMAiRRfEKPEYWAfJzddBnmfeaG6Wq3dnmQA4N8sZpDjc9XmpkDYKAa8GSan/J2jVID@up5hU26AGiNt1iQemKhTPSqneFMvyr7//xf/Bfv39z37FfvjzX/2//@l/Rve/x5//ADoLK4URfvozRtYb8POvGNlqkN1IlIjir5blH37xS3j9n/4t@@EnP@NBf/IXcnYtBAQh6BWl/Pk/w58/wJ//U86uhxF//kc8IiaRs7dSQrVSINZP/5oxyA2hhMB@8ZeMyRlQMBTBeQ3expuxkxU4gJAMDXI1p8P5L95RBjQuqBkZ4Iq3YvSWwQpQY8A9Ha@LjdoeqDN8hhKltKEbPdw9L7xcH/UfA1UY19e6wG/XbVB6xOREGkr/@6zM0hmMg9MoeERMlctwUX5RbjkKxbgZOQ/Y4T1HAhTd4BZiAsNbCfibRgITX8NhC41Ii5xHBH1f4XXUQQciB5xFF1pJIq8gNU7CiMs96YazYKiLTIvdED9ihS72ksT27mIsw4S4mao2yGXaB4aM0aEL8aTkYfYHUCWQLKQ3EhZfiArZaXBRzYlms390MNVg8NMCFfMyLpHCjKpMlu@Ji5QW8VXUuFaT8Tm@IkKjUF5tJo5wmBdZ/vrrr2Up5ldAHvLaCkGIFYqLjDComAwqxYJKsSDAmcMkWbNeKk3hQB0HysXkcSU8WUxEJZNFzIUtJ6gHRAPGgnz6M9uxR36vOguaJHJS2M0Cj4EsNquinZw7JHNqTFZnEgDMZJrqdF3OB12YiTNbUfNTIrUTPonaWgwpkSbWKIh60jSVwporbs@ruWSGd4AuNjMPzKhU@B0zyj0wo431@zOarlZMmwC/mL73i51ATIQSPgLGG34q0UFh1/gLYL1IHCHGHjkVFYY8dTHkaV27TJlziyv454ODixNXt3qx44xxEPPKHZp8euDpwIUhh4tacOym6NciemLYwa9Y7zquZ/rxo1ksvnndSePhQIbbdaBXy@IBypa4lxjtBvi5ecl@JezZhBa6y6@RR9CcUKh5XlxYjjW8uADl0@6oEQHxVTNwR3FawvvnwRVLr4Sq7dFAcfEg@KF6P0zSd3myM8u4VI4GIjANmdQZDOgM04bBF@vhDZW@y0mCReR3VoJG2hoqdFpjz@27XdNx8VwkTD0F/jCCjQjpgwHhkmV6lhkxjMQgWjGyuiqSfvnJSdmXJbxjNUhfSgJIECPLvGkaI2W9OdldLMyOJwvyO/10fE/j@J7ejW/H8vzhNM7kibM9@Py0rFeVCAJEjNBYvR@NrDgKbQadBCqhN96OzBM8GMU2GTO1EdM6RK2L6FoH@CMbvvm0d1gg/tUi@t9dgUHy/YdWHymzpxOQN326zJSGaH6wlq5A9ENVjawRY9mFrL33wLzEQIdGeFkmk@BycGM6NMzBwHTwPk3@CQDfw/No0DTD92TlVOWBc3DyrrLssrS4ivYu2qatT8y2ImJmY3CDEp@Yepvk1cMKjoKOhJ7Lr8RWCtliQhWjA0QoUnkBy@jZK1VdzFY8ihVyDy3GEYaHi@lHE3fTohknQat8DcT1QIKm6IxBOtlxMBlM@KFDNp0GFshR3v/wmnyFZzHdSxCgA78ytpiNslXvEp8nSlikB/QIYVwtWWTauh90Wy5o4zN1@Gkkur@kNMsQJqoGtZzQThbVuHVXjce4IuBJrpU8jCXvY7oH81yM1TiwSITtfloXMgN5V7dtw1DiELnPnTXmOjMyAf2wxlxnQa9yMUeghilJ0g3x4roq1y9UyQLnITyv4PkVPBEgjEEvOEMFZUO9NpjyopC@PohpLcKnYaAuGqOiGl9HjMWSAjdO5N6GeRoL8zRm8jQSeYYtIJllLJJkJLIUtYDVc1cV2GZnuEA6YxCO3OFxl9iGj@PqHq693qStdNnKsvRVugwCOW2my/sKCOV0O13eI4efLp@S4zJd/hIcUdtKf0yXg2aBETx4JcdT9BciHN@NdHlXUW@lIR6wGuSrpcthnUKcJ/yVKHLLp1dbYtXfDWdVTbzvHJXKLEOO8eHhYrEazSx9C/BPUcXBvRC4VGWlFYqMA5BEpxHrMXg@0G1oeGO9p8zrPsrB1JSY34jmUCA8U41NqiCXjEgepVPppDDiiGEoTT7CExBEuVmejxErzozM7kNH5G7hTfNA7GT@RD2N9IG2QuENiByfxLGj9EF9JUHwCnwYnph4EZ4z6ATZEUZoDKDOQQuJ@i59R6GwrqcOgeW1H6@h2TkCrMRcEIXXEoGNyXTQ4VA3pcwG7iDJJBSKq31WPA1@RKNE7p1KRlJBtMwFweQtSoaCId741buKE0uHqCVEEAY2Ck3eysJ@gWQxBkWyLqap8sYHKMRkTptOZTORbfeEk@JxcZOlvmJRNxSk5VmS5EqKSUis4UEGI33Ic4/WZfB4g08bvgYpx3j8u4IAYinDXLh8dT9Bf3e5/h4o1AERpjKYp1jP70pn1es7e9kpzO0o29kKxMAs21PnKkdhDhHJYXQQ08zv4rUZFR/vOOZKPs80hD6l7QdkC8cE99BtemzBYaGW4F0lPS9xYvaytJhQsxqJfaUFSouGOQk4vOAhplHR7saVF3xeFWMI9tHw@OQK9pIVHK88hEcF8KZIzlu5N3LIvCpq23S2VrRywVcdXLQSC480jnmCuCf7tdBECzyOLk72jl69@AY63c3NTXV2KQJbLaSN@nHpzmWCcNhSyuKplHiQNtlO9FxvuHTuyLMmZeQByoBO6zac/UQbV4Usi8nzqbYL6XjcGEUFrMuoGegJqYSqjo5dtiXoyi/WUlZ0ASRQb4HeWRqt4aoRcgcu6FxcUPd1cYHGORcXohfDqgmXkX6TEldslyJ7DXAlrJlI4/Jnjn7DCYBRn3Y6BRNw4lA3boeSAjiHwyB1mGrkDK3A2AHnh2i/Y7CWr6wWcXbisBP6EB5olKGU1nAIW1rHc2F4KoyNE59kWinyWeKKDt5t4A9ch06nphM/SW3Hmxb8YOqV0B451zqZgfBc6DibGEbcICtYF3Mdfu2Az9PixkqaQg5ok2VmV6MVn9I2DDkurQE/tDg0/fBVSkQIk40W0Lhlm31A6RR4d85s8ksLaqV3YHW7wEh5cVscN3A50yFpzu3kdoPD@FLsK9222sGx8MImjK5kEPPAQE4lcZqiz0oboE1tZ4Gy0RcIi2YyDE9MLJCRFsWC7yY8NrlzKxtLu6RM1OSzGHxUhLekXGDN8t3sloc3w13pTozO9PkYn5oWi5YkB2Irl8H5fZI4yLVK65Qa2qgNFDklBwf7oZObTei2EZwzqOAJl2XpkUOCBy3AmMFta0DBdVBpo@U1NTRJddhnbLUk0WUULk0u82wBBl/ZS0CHMEiKyHLrPiFg5M/a8me4mCg9SqEs5LyG6QNWRjcdEB/xMlsS4PiCCjZl3gSCl/XYyyoMNR7NyXhJkTMAJSOrcgISxBerH4@45J1NCkIRxMOnmmKbnudQNOkKRAmja36FGXHlDsNesuxF88GEXS8OpuKGmh1hv8bvxsrKr9ECq8wzob5Dw3NbUXRXpmV3rhiYa9ID7aTZCu0i7iQ6GtnDxCEaS5ZzFwLUoxCHopwh86/P/DJ8AYdsABLIRBYLCtFGvRc3ogjaUePZE4VmJdalKMU4NohgxweB0gF6ZuXP0Gr1MSSkLhb6O3We2lSoJNIDcv7AIUtuOafJlFRYHSOkJAhem@gf2r5KZPAeCK47TqLX88WtwsY22U8zJzvM9hvbzeyKUZWZObR0p@@PvOv2ZdftXYGywAbvW2Nj8uFbxtbXGG4oKT3m@@uLG9U8baHfpDMotuk0p@XggAs6peFcZox28eJ5GmnGwu1FlSXcWA@fLP6U5coMl7KVfsCF3Ii639hoVp1qodJvOM2Kk8mow0x1mClmFPR4XFQrIGn5tEtj2CSryPwKexmYLuI5rTi36nbYsesYPTftM7pgM76mR3vGggbU1wfx9nQFow7Xi/t0kJ/0fqIhznrRvVNTKS03iDecDEwUjaHVp423E@PPo9HGWmU2HEv46BGaKFeEbhovwI00GLVsywAZRPREFQPNFctlYXRvMORbEFDoZ3FPjgv0QAoGV4JQwx1MRGKLR7kIyrITA1lTsO9Ssw@JGcRqAU9e4Kn6HkTjUTh5E9EZgKauR@VYofuF6YT9DO6TUCtoRc6WgrBgRwXGR76hfQ0XoP7RLgh47DARlWyMmSosesm3YaFRAalqtTQPevR@1B9Q/65xfAVF8Mqgi4FueWFKzR/hdV8KKyIxrABprAF03OIuvCtQLONVE9QFTizQ4jaWB@Ed07nPgLCh40WFIBtxcQfhtV1K84jfSaVAJ8gnrjgaIi0VQxVVDYTDQ9PSg3SZ0TxDBbyoy6nEQt9DKJZ1QXAfgvv6sLcguIewR/6iYA@C8aaqBcEWBHObk/nhLoRzTWpBhCHOogG7Xgzdi6Fu2Qo3mEZT61susBWWyQSEDVmA8Yrh9ZFMz4TpOVvitcOZLcFe0D6JrXgEZGlFNB58j7iFQvF0DYXzRSxPThN2w@7NTEw@AYkvKCcQu5i/upKAz2IIQPsDUcpmw4PMeW2HBU3wjwbdThdrG4i1yj5@vAszwYhJ/is2A@7jNYTznLEScmpFcPhFOlG98kQfRKL5aYRpfly6BTpoVI6gUZYiEcLbVtSuOxboi5BURS0n8sYhpcqeRD4Nv8nKofSI6Mibxf10LM1wD444qUVmWStyGg@nqo58Dyl16JFbkbDAfVh6ZYacfhg7l4xdg9ghNaf4zEjwjGiln1rYh5UmBfhRoybaVLigNUA1rAkE56Cn83qNywQObDld5v547Y@VBGYtAMb3K14AgOEO4IA9WyDGgz7RcjRu8wNyvlBay9IUPo9yG5EpEFYPodM/QONCwokue4Q3ISRFEptDmpnoYbmRXrXpJjdVPC7p5xeuwY3G0k/SiCOb5SfiuifQS5ZZgYUbYyrs9n459NtR5iaqvoS@4yuLZUVQ6QEnPoQFbxcQ@l4mSxah1GQJio/osvvBvV0SbfKc3ylFSxcXgU8wrcXb9kINDLGqJMMRZw4wCABFOZ4qK3SuWiQ6xe7Wi2Gg3GQjLQwvIOJcASp7RYqLcxzOHVDnHfcNt@YQReIhaCmIGqYXYGZ1At0W1OAgnWZcYDVzIiM9oU13XbetBAqTUBgIQmABDZGyfLtQqFZx9TLKHrITSi/rCivqoN@tgM@S8KJ@BTxQ@RS8iUisdKnZVLDZxPQby6f7sSgceyPIKljdwckgLn1YedofY4cq0KO5iQKJj3u@aGewkPPUEyfEg7yrOzjxRmd/0dB6R0b/sCIwTg0G2tH@YaqD2zmzDHyPtNg9fBMfulgVS0OdOKz0YJZJrYTY7OzImE100MZvUkv5ke/RjcqmcwVKdWsipZjp8BsSynjLaG4LJ2LxklAhTWjemyZ5gE2gpjA3zTGvFXGRKO7SllWJ7/mjSaGihOdB0Ly8bV61QevnFvED1x/T7wQGCwVtNBi6FCIyor2B7KP1MdqvXqBVWjFiEOjsEJwojoLrN9x3wueickWuIBXxrAs1BqKBKUngyueyjPWHiIr5ukZT8jVTN3qIBPLeRz6cguoiTr6V/KDqcS8bkgIXB8FpcyveAc3NYRaknfgTeofi43sRHdyHphCR78U4RaIJVwyxXXeATI5TbZh@BwjACf/o9Gxv/@REE4cb8xUBXEXg88RogkEbAsUlwGKaFFcDcDsmr5RHWFiEzfOrRsBJ/hKNMFtBJmwK10hOTivc78lLkCvS20wxwvgqj04koeVk8eYjLQvCanoAehTSLkqmxJLlgmRB5BgpHt1LDd0w0ND2pdl3AeNduoa6yGnxKCIHOpEiQf6ZMH@/gXk2Q@R5eG4mPJcI13g4RyqKpRk9L4pUjkeSUzdRvFsmR9GyM3lVGRT68BXt3tFcL4Z35a64vgaDNCuKXAurknNlGLCTCMjFQt7OqX0espRIEzJ4GN7g4YK/S6LmQywTcZ8m88enJCrIJBtXYRIyxaWaY9n8YuoohCQsw20rPDnWN7Edb5RiQkSIkxyICbylF5ttrRpByRQDiUNtRq7tPJU1MSX1RJlGQ@V32U43rDltJEYlyjNDhBtTTwL5UPBSDATBREZjQcutBYknIvEkBhZjLQXZSsFO7GQDh6JNN/EqTpt/xJ@gsSeRC@Kl5gc@4piPeeH5SlaSQCR0l@T5ZEpKk6E3MrmnKNQdvUiU92Qa4nwh8crFEajRo8uYgzxNvt7WcUdOeymUE3FBEUiKGbqHIYLSUYRiwL6LqhADb6Xf5Fekz/U@aIW2OWZ11Kl1OiFJSixm4vXJPp4mhmdVMn80GNiW2DfHrmm5jJezWFrHxZ4IYkxp0KRDNMDh8bPoEouPkEhjRwj5Gu04ogAfL9Smi1gZ3vQGorVjAcihJtWdCb8jFreZlfiSoslGPr9SnW6OjyHBa463nvDeXU0KFm55UTu8fTtDUIGg4K7HLxR3O2VJ@tHIMi53P2elQmGzWFgtxkgWTFUXtNW1@H3gYUCpUCwU1otrkrTrDibcdEQxVIS1lkOAWfYCO/qvgDfNK7yJTapDj0ER8aBL3/SuzLYmSSdmm@aAWyOiCLIyXs1Op1TQPnr0Ad0KzxPCy4r9LL@RGDgMn9g/87MBDDJczkq4Rjswvb415Cu57hW/kz5Yl@64tu1e00Q0LglzemCivjkEoqyoLIkS7fsXuJDuQtvxgRq6uDBWb7lXdE6HIAPoqRYeb0QLrBJuUkUI8cz4bZMxTCA/w9atPrLTHARwF0tEgQABKFp7ZJh34iAREp@IQ3ATbts1RnjygR7UTB6kn0ttBZq76VkgfSMCU61QshjuUMFnzw9P2enRwdmb@sk@A/fxydFXh3v7e@zZN@zs@T7bPTr@hg5zZc@PXoB0OWX1V3vg@@rs5PDZ67Mj8JDrp5BSpgCp/uobtv/18cn@6Sk7OmGHL49fHAI0AH9Sf3V2uH@aZYevdl@8hs768ywDCOzV0Rl7cfjy8AyinR1lKdcgmRSlY0cH7OX@ye5zeK0/O3xxePYN5XhwePYKMzuA3OrsuH5ydrj7@kX9hB2/Pjk@Ot1nWDBp7/B090X98OX@ngb5Q55s/6v9V2fs9Hn9xYupgh69ebV/gsgnSvlsH7CsP3uxTzlROfcOT/Z3z7BAkWsXiAcIvsiy0@P93UN07H@9D8Wpn3yTFUBP93/0GiJBINurv6x/DoWTlHuoAvWy@/pk/yUiDZQ4ff3s9Ozw7PXZPvv86GiPaH26f/LV4e7@aYVJL45OiWCvT/ezDK9yoawBBlALwsH97PXpIdHt8NUZ9Bmvj88Oj16pUMlvgDCAZR2S7hGBj17x0gKRjk6@QahIB6qALHvzfB/8T5CmRK06UuEUqLZ7Fo8GGQIRz@LFZK/2P39x@Pn@q919DD5CMG8OT/dVqLDDU4wAMDHfN3XI9DWVGusJ8OJOYFYp4NwsVSc7PGD1va8OEXMRGzjg9FBwC5Ft97mgObTlvDR3ye3OBbzZVT4xFXL3ITy7R3v7oPHxc/jkyP81dDpbycW7RBh0NGEgvIpVUOqrLtpma9S9wFvicWgeJuMr2H2/m8WTLFW8eudcuuteOL5QTglSqYuLr@oXMM49vbhQsw9JmUDjvhRil/tdsVRRRtvV2zTMT8wtxQlVeyzO0snygy3icy2Pw8kHleXzbVMkQ@MQBBxME4lDnwBYGyUjWY3oDotlSUvMybkiOpFserIoWN50ffhxPkYvvG@IeYBw5nYL@TyOYQkNPFmOhfhDJnTomjh5jewArA5lqfmmedlVCvHscMgvJqjUIA3FHcIwsKuo9yRvmd2p5Lnp9IQs2vKQshIctxMcg8Ov6MU3QTIm6kXzqGQKn9qjhxpgQxmBUqjyrMhQSFifKI95cty/zecK1Up4VAsdt/ay/vXhGxzMFUprlSn/56E/b1to1YdnB0J/16B0TXo8b/II0MAsHH4BSawJX1LN52NpQCsjfTKMjGcB9TDStdWGPhW76p5J3TqeQMSPY4inh87Ys8Zx7EEMf35Sf/ns9cEBSE7Edm1rfXOjIokTjbzh11n@/AbzwaNxibqgRV9boKZRUKyV7ILeczBzGGHs9ESsPYyIR48HlUaeeEVxuDOZ6wj8/DI@DYTF9fEEJwcPMZPxECZP5pdwL0kBv85tmYIBlERRVSxNXx@Thq@DqkQ8YPBdyPaEam2MPwg7bP5BEw8LJBhIsJjZHwwnwLkwuCC5Jx8EBp00tiGzLYyiyQEfD/TABokTBmUmWbmijSO9Cd6O1SLotVjR2F6p2iklILE0jUVwCB4daQlZHLt@0IK5pwU@Xwt@A@c34vBFDMKjtOrDUyDjQZgyFxyOyOecRcMQkJu1KlTR48dhTjsMJ1JVgRSf/08ezRdvDYQKN2hgU4ADy6OQzmEITUI/TavshnMqnpqCcCqCY8U7cO684ggoleDIGfEenNDHOKzowD7yug7zkIIo3wRRQnImyPQ70YPg/zekyRz4OzDgBOgRtUgOW87IfCAlCSqnFYxeiSjWdWAxFjNTi6gZ9/omAnMbr5heWDBhhjfmC0tAAlE7k8DjG35kqzKHAMjkOK8Rb794QAI14p4OI6en1HYf8ZV@zzH6AyU48DToKmbgNrOkc2UDEzl8UfkSfoHFsnuB59c9pX20JDNwwAVSrDVhn/kyh5EpkszBQudXaNIjbOXEmkiGYtDCI3YqiKYVNP6xsDCKepl2EHoLqujiw1TD5RA8szEh8IMVkECAkO1TvMCCbJBnDRGdW260pKdZfiZ6cTxxHEQg9cvsjMyffb1DY2bsioStMhpFY5YI57O2OBOzZQ6vsbuwOXSy0Y6gMeUzMhPHTMRcZKhGBMJX1YDq1Mleh9jTNCXya4j9a@fSwVs3TD7FFcTQEidsxre4a@ylTodt2g8rtxxlnkGy1pL5Hzpkt27w9UqcmqORO@SCI/3P/IgioHFeo3YJ/VBEJd24RE854FHrOmeN4UF55UTJgzMjYcxAJwLPU/pvFw4IkFembGCZfO6Ek0hl3pFVPwvUF3Txthu6vkGXmGeuQqEAOfBBg1mhBiHKqDehkeZsayP8EtsW0Pi0DJrT9bXW0kd93enofcuekNXpe7fn5H1n5A/w8nlZlpOzgXjQCpqgA@5Dk72xnLZ77bNn0BxwIun01evT4@TEX2zma5fPfDH2BeTBnlHO0gz4Du5J8d3OEKrGrLCJuI/Ji6Z7aJ5QzLTQtNYEPXDjj0cMBPn2Q83481ev2eemY3qgDx6TzSV7YRmmA@IDlCmywvR7XNJg9APM/VTkzg5Qd6GZnQozLZrUCef2JJGBgJZF1lKgKQLCnji2GufmJ8DqsTlBbbbAUbnawaRSzx2I3RY4aYrKJp/i7IzsrIRnY785PHuOg3E@MKe5GejWgrk@nEvkqlOfT9ZCYTzdGU6AKNL05A2gfd/cjcZoswVAlBaTkwZ1fbysp43TfrYPRcXLtIQUoB4EmqppXeFhvDQN95A6IjtbMW0W0a0i9q9m@fHAgehI1J4U1V4Wz2TXsmx9m52ZyLvs2NYNGGGx0xEmX10FPfCZ6w8x6ss6Y4VSsVjMFVdxivb1aV2jhoDf4IRWSTp8eXx0cgaEFEcQBYwR9plIfDoUlVtjATlyeDQqlP4dCuQgPkjM0jsiHqrgwTkJcoWvWMhlGere0HG6F0roJ9VhmpLFKXnXo4NZcbcNsFCiOUKu/jUKX740QjnFoGfpaFhxuCvvWkI8abckJXiHuNnAVzauh76jxOQHAsAckx@k8mhk0BbHCkGd9M1@iL01DHp3nUeQps@UDQnG51KBOdLZNGpJQD01Dqdtoo2Ej6cz9f0rwwPZol8By6EJS7DlCHiGZJMalkZvWbYFbQDwMnoudjhcXAUVQVMQ8RNnJarx8CxD7JAIlzmnQUHrarv9MCrHSpLCzXbCf@BPDJelujDMxpGWPzDNNp1ENRrwo5YwXINWbkPPwbfhlaMzmKRUgewmPRA2eOQdyL6RjXvzcS9li9e5FJQGuCrYvnnWw2E9BwQlOh1SI8UTcZU5I@wsw3VelapdB4bAtCoSYsFGSgAxyOKiFGAF9U0MQS5ilyxu97Gpvqf3WWJCOuzRHyQDEBZf1TWTAQF4LLtwzkTgTFoNEZjawhkgw/chcXdiDiz5guVFu1PclKbwMkLhJmpIzAMLjyjncwMu67r4i5G1gGJ8jdCkNcKZjaF4c2YR4E3HLM7GhFjhAW2xmKU5MHNzYa7Oh5kTMMVi5aFzRRviMBWxBS8FP23DBfmIhIiK/7kbiF7atme7fIEpLH3Xdlt4LiZICsgNH5NsVLFxbxqBJQgdD@WbNJPnee4ERRKoi71Nge7CdqB9mDW2E8xY1M4dXlEioMrbEu0JY9R3UXMiJ/6IFkVOOXE4KGodU6eDInrcF2Q3gpUFSOEjl1nUMtESJx5f5JxM0k8kKU4lEcglk7QSSUpStBN8qnYxBYp@fCZLFuglZJVENcCqYQUVpL4@5qObAm3wo2kaPJI7seOw1BQMghEbBgv3DGL0phQdgZFYtud5BK9kgkcW3/KyTEeKFpLnSY0D0z0SAxQrET6hY1YcRRRIFWSgl/B4DTVARpRrh5I4MUkVFpgHSIlie7hXS4nnopZZaqDzVUOM5WPHFs@6QTTAVXoZ/laYIjLIxZHlkfDYAiEKgfB0tEUDhrK8WgI5WJCinpneYgIOalDi8ptMxng3oCiJdhVI7hAmd87IbgCF/hwc5STx/dU@6HXcF3uUmGg4RYUPj4kXSp45huEZrTETCOp/whlr4cnPjAilh0C@EeXcDHqNZCkWxp7uSubFifUqIRXuihwQO6TTwsiLexsiHc4hoLzj0WOke4GTxIJ0QRec9jnJSEuxhrSZ3DUsLqGSZIsJXZ42O0cAJ6s8QC47VSopdlSMKOF0NyIles4EkyixN7wGh33GDwrmgFQpkQrpv6jC0dwx3rAXxivyeKLaF3FECCuo97vYIowc1PtdbMEjx6r9brYIzooOSUvpp/kiUROcBGiUKEYMNKcUl0FBwDgeazwVixCaNONnxZi2MgfbmFQVc53SjKoUkkgcDZfMgx5jXjEpsZE7wY5AvEZYG82otNDHGZdmOzzxQpQ@HCLV5GSXwGtz@qAnLHSQA9VRU8UrScIEILH5JJgYM/e57SadGJTmAxYag@KpqN1ecndvAmzQqxTUWYUyOB0pQn5nLvK52VOqoiFWefb@ndC6TGCNBk@u18bYsjRnxVe6B6tMDKtk6WI1lCTxAki5B0HKPQBSPgZJNOxV6C/JmfLwHGDzPhDn57Mw6PEWBlICBkjatoWT2DgOvtYn98FcAmUrRTZ1OrcqCxNEevJ9MJ5Mw6Bz13vhapzw7Ok46/bB9NzpU88WUjbJK3MwCrFKzaKVRbRIatN4V8QLVCUa22qXrZ4VjgRS99c0PydCJEZT4l64CJRKnloUAovaf3EB/bKxak22B454YhoGtGXpE5uDhoTgM0x8q1iYICbIkuNQEZAkxN2h08KPRqvTp0vggfILk6n3luQpn/CJTToVoWhcYiU4LhjCRcIp6K0C@TZveHZv/qm5@Q/cAeg4nbkIUPw@zuPzSakpkR6pplND6wf1ZXP7s9lyxfW2qbPfHt7IH88UvQRFx43p0Kgd81r0/ndBFmUJauC30OQbAY8sQPKzuUjiQrsuJreYM@q3TE96SFPnKTR88DHSYs6VpFSK1Q0YMouTh@gGKDoe2RRZohqMjOCz0QDXa3xu3ImNG@fITM7A03HxOniKrcmYBc3R9k3dEUcRiQ6z6@H6RRg3i8ej4@YuysFyDCC0b8amP9/xOz/apghBi@Q7yFqZX/fI1XRdPcciG@Uk0OK6pjJJjmm57wIFJ9RqKFZ5WlEJeAcXQ1e4Zi70JVDM1flTYA/Rnu5SiICJF2UpBrxToO/m0fJiYo4GISnDqnkAKeepW@Es9wPUrclD1a3/BpScrlAp5hbag@hgy/cKtelBPl14Gxx83Z9zdMtXZwcHiQNPWpNgVNA3vfVCoYCH4MzcbocLFLhKbLn5ZOw8zonnB9dfeF@18pg0eZ/d3OvsEAeIirFxaQL5BJcmRtDfxI7TwvkcB3flvPd5TH4CT5uRGacVGrd/dUbMRyCReGaZvcMCYvneseByaVAc@ZBBQAnszSA1qqFXcmAmB@RBjw6eqBOapBEwGjeLXQu48FGt3UiPxBWPNM@H1/GoN9E2RPm5adtulr1xPbu9JPPdockEBwfxBAUeBU0JeePx6XqILDOvLDt2RQZGQdxc29Rst8vvWML7c/nsJ@1l8swBrqQp2I@dmN398UCRG29lYEwocgaLmWFyE7f3dGXoomRaQr8fLD@QDNB@UOy@PlAMotN0ZOgDxV6qyAUYreIlmtw6GOdTdqHIaMyhJKKo/FwYTrP7YyNR56OrvXctR4GiY7CE2@Vo6zdVL5VkQfSQuPL5uNhBGhY4DIETHoH4sBS3FTx06rf/4Ow2zhzg5kaa4w23xMbOG4uXI5iMx5bFroadDjQvPhNfC44aC8CRqMwVyUoBSSMq1jO/HYE@o6Q7fpofYIemNqcTx0gg0ig1syw9Gna20gDhdyqjFLRA0fyAnmg28WUOmvXBiO5JieQZTcOhAcWs3MEEF5hAkj4zqt9eK/V6nS0PMhlWrz8DRy7H6s/qbA89nj1je/D@DN8fV0vr6xVuOben3oDns8Dzlj0DGNQF4Z1se/AKYXTVEg6lsIqX89XlbGX5orpTq/j5Rv1ZM5/vguvvfv8nf/dP/yRfFy/f48szemm8DSNpmpZfNm6WH99W8L2x10wvtxrLg2a6W0EuQ3H/2vN1W49tE9OMf5B7cYOd84bKQKNVq9U0S3/8yF3nw8jpRU68xCBKrtuDnk7JGUGoVdP19OPH4Nqppn@cVvHkDuGvh/4fwJ@pKMtpvZhIS8vH9dPdw8P4PUHh/aMd1DRxwV0XxmmW41tQqHepYPU812Caxpo59i5EDw26L3jEJIosjRajHJnvBJJB6RCzAAA1B7mZQ4O0aq5R3Fhv5lKplMzN1CzCjNunkgUSN4zi5mp9v0v2R4EFE4WRtRgm@qxd5rZ1BCMDEhHjV/iuVYW3xweZwkFHE94pzm4Y3Xcr82tcJ7Hr9WJX6@IZItP3rofn1kY3r9PF6wFAY@psg2mA3PQOxstUJ2gJyLByxTt04LPV9E7cf8PWgrUasYfdtSddG6@jpG0I/jW0d6C7Kq5Itp3gnEHMgadsmR1cSuRthCgW2wZHqpaJu0sdA@froaN1bDyWlqtQwUXEoJMBh6HOIE626OAuasV2uPG92wGnipfGBxcuU71l6LgkqhNcF7Hp0BWePmhZKwPQBgc8JlIV3iPDVSwDmU0Lk4dHsyaMA1WkpCUy3E0KzDpooI1csRkcj68K1pN7/X4f5AlnstAYBvS1Pg7ucLoBiIMpNDrLFRrdhL2znXfzLmQm@z/KmmdX4ja@IAvC7CyxpEnZ8e20sspLhSe/OvpQkHng@r4lTEBEdZF9C99/6wHU87TEMxNcE7@yemVABU1FGdu8dXKWMsfA7zjDxE/zgNyhkIIbEhHRLBJt@rjFWSph6Ur3lqMwa5lDy@CbkHjuS4GUG9BBG@jLTyRZmBGo5dzQMqhoyuGcif2dwsaSqjyCQ3TC/b7MHxm9UKnViWaB8Q7HNzgPZdAImSSsnfOISBHEkBMIQJIoAkea9hEUfJRgUNvsWsNEmizfzix2bvJS3Aakx8b@jmwJY9Sdoixa3QR3Roei4Z2gd2DePABxFISBpNzidsvzeS8oDPYX3MopTMmLREdSbM3yRyiXAnTiWENLBvJhM84ma4i6LexFLJ/zMa@TiFVZVAt35kDABYpcbqzQHnkCIKTGNE1yDbw5d4oaIFanmkEkjQsJ8DEGRuaO95Ekq6bIy6uLd7YzQjzglwDT2zk3wf9j5puoypaHh7hC44NYyAegCkRm2i2I4RiR3hCCnNsCr81ABUYxbNHOIG9kg07Nzb9FzxK/bD3KNMRjKqug6KKGc6SDDIKjwBrpeF1OJQ3KG6VuJlPn0vxUhJvgbIQ4x3CNWogKGsLxaVtxkIJI84h39dDXBrnxoxCUQvB6G5zZII48CC3BgzoTFUGdr95BoqFtOcr4qMpu5zFMMGYOZH9ACaF3oClKHPj/19619LZtBOGz@CvWEmJbrBxZSdEgfQRwbjk0AdLebEBiKdoVYIuClmorFP7vnflm9kFqYcuG26aFL4ZMch8zuzvzzezOLOpCrh/9Lj5fn2DdLVwmZ5um/tA8PYaGrwy9WVxGyHGzbAg1FAQ7FUAUw7H@op/nuDL6iWA4j/WCBlsiQwpb0e8sE1yiFl3/R3v1vv7j@HR00b/ojybfvB32YZd6lDYoLSGHQVnxCeY1o/JKbT3Sz3oi7bdKBPv6l8V8TnhELyugotqafzXVas/ZI/2nF4L2BAq4D9Fe9SMJb09oEPFAeY3fq3VxdVPg58f653Wx/UCqCf9@Wsp4/sT1fSYVxZeW4s1nWblncwIg/Vu2S8Oc2ItEuKgLwkNlA8DQVJKawIOIBAOqHQZIm55@2yY2YkNMv/gKPLaGNqVBnQlusXIWeyY5@GYwEDgcgOyiqTyjuan2h0X@OPmJV2IudOElv3CRM9FTKSGGwLV5x2VaKfRCBjNMvGO0JqVG5pom6CksmHtJqSXScOZ7b2dq9jTlr9ObzXWzUMp2yHJ0caGREVZs@EYPJZOz9nH2ucUPHHD0PV4inbFD8Oyi6/IuooPrPV/QKg2WDgRV4IKaaK6WEm4p10v0A/TDzReghBoykjH91deYH6e3390xNoL93zlDhBOac9K0aDhAL/M8MkYkw5/XvsZTfdAyTbgfxBTuRr5imSyi@TYeYx5hTrkOYeIH99kEvtsElifMsmngkrNa9diyyDAR0uy9RrzuyJyewDsf27w0U1DY1jfudKMaGZFpG12rTCuII7b/bXP2HnuuhQkjVrl4yBjRHLQWWgsyukC0iJ0exEAzx6MAWmMwEiMJiJyVZhwTPvejJJGs6xNiQ0wV@lL63IXeDjF5ShPijarYUZ4jDyN2Xg21qZ5HQPiU5tTcCVXVbkGx6eYre9GCBnN9bSPNGMiboEADkk2Y5n4a3MuoapdRk8cxSvqV4pO8eTI2tRnQ5tJtlqWmrxcdGqAZr3Ufm78jl8C4Aw@EO3UkgC72EaOOdaujAXTI/q0Dw7k5uyKx2MbCsktfhGdiC4lZaTu5mLybTkJYNuvqW0LEhK4ydj8dQ0ohHq3lFyHIOs78R8i8wNwAv72PQnOBmfFgmOlO6FgvvZ@8mQzRyB4tZa17Kh4M70UM8tbH5U5aCVYogBy5mWpqjvu1H3RdQsXR6mrTB6WHBA0RpCCJvEJ1QTznqxWHyEJFlFEKBSAIuWeFl9t44K6kMlS9GZoXJXXksFQdt@T1C6di6VeyRxYQ6LiWMhMPyivRQez9GQ@yHnVBkAYfkKLGUPordf/aishYuRAVcfaGRBtiH@LsEcdB9MKsxe52FXQiWDFnrxgjdd6L3v6t0MDx2CIFvp8BHiCcOnTA@Ixr1QFWhICje1igRy/sEbHaB6gnWwlQDXARrG3NZKfBJ6qqk24iPyrQ0tZ5GgG1I19j0pfq/EZmkCxmjiWetrjGVk1Vspvc@67sMPISqzNifOSyM3O3JAWJr7IlrmJyDg@N9g0O7Q7GSBr6LUZJP1rMuFiKcO5OXRJC/BCMV5VCy8SjvlXS/yAf6BdhdR6mgQiL14BDgt9mHPi@WXrOp7mDonfxhwm6qjuh@@CJXPjmkiqG3mQPZWiXn/dMUrj5/juz9EEjse9U9YnJ03NRdPGbiejiWPds7Zi9Dax9JP@9ZNBBypagf0wepzXqif6Fm4L@yATle7KKxqfnImlvm@Dy83bdS9tAfXGh6G4v0UnFfE7qeMPR79uGquDAd9z2FvFZClmYFA9TmM5Il@ZVFJKJyV3pWmZaOthlBoZZZP66fF/g1KUmSOpRdTjOgxwpvKFVl5Jxiw/dsXMA5zhh107ELGKDSAqe87@auKR3Kfm/L3UlCwUmn2qzSoP2B0QIxnq/Lpq9IFbYqJNocrPk7Kuc278zD@3LjC@pfCgk2weX5XvjskEOT3ce4Fk@WBG2eP3IOv5ZnNbe2vc97/NChVsfJgexmAboejuKXfwqteKNuMfDvmf48qUqhvyLhy@5Z3/ZBjF5ADFlEsSED7RUyY43lPPfQzzQsl3CQs4V9kh7dbs9WjeuvTrZnq04o68J32nhGs3y40Szze@1lvATVRvUzatEQyxrZU3P@rq2Z@Z4d0HLeAc1/PpZDf@f1fBf)

[Online compiler](http://try.brat-lang.org/#) is not up to date currently, use [local version](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brat).
To build on Fedora you may need to `sudo yum install openssl-devel` and remove `-Werror` from `brat/src/common/turbo/deps/http-parser/Makefile`.
**Update:**  Compilation is slow (9-15 sec), so I included abstraction test in the test driver.

Brat block comment is `#* *#`. Block comments nest and allowed to be unclosed at end of file. 
Before this addition there were no `#*` or `*#` in the polyglot.
Brat block comment starts on line 4. Main code is on line 32: `*#p 173#*`.

Comment: VIP score: .001727

Answer (score 5):

## 174. Haskell with MagicHash, 8967 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@"/*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(      7 >77*,68*,@'_          7 )(22)S/ \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x           -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@         /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRt-VkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcTcxxxxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9      L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                     _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*.*]*.*(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00        ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x!<******>**********************828+*+@[*99[?]*]*****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss       e$P+ + + + + *D* + + +1+ +1E!s
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
[mxf]-main=-[165]-###jxf*#p 173#*s 
#  
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<

>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 

\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   ) --s
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796loTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<W
>instance Num B where
> fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer}
>g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1
>y#a=128
>x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8  \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3         \=#print(   size([[1] [3]][1,:] )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#   print(171)#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//  $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es^*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee<*s 5>1  *e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001702 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9121 bytes)

### Explanation

This answer used the technique for determining if MagicHash is being used that was discoverd by H.PWiz in [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153746/56656).  They have a full explanation there.

The Haskell part of the current code is

```
import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
instance Num B where
 fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
data B=B{u::Integer}
x=1
y#a=128
x#a=174
main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xTsMwEIZ3P4WbZg2KI5BRsDuEpQygDqCgRhE6ua5jkTiV7ahBpK@OSRAD3HD3/9Kn@xpw77JtQ9DdqbceP8vRX22llYdeJEn5bxgrkTbOgxESPw0dLvC5mVGEj7bvHoyXSlr8xgtMaHpnpAIvlxqP6xEpXi3stCyWROWmjGr813BD09n/YkRGGavOU40O4AEXvPgc8vz3@wWNnKCPNXCS3aJxufQadaANP1ltfNyC8zGhWV4NcZWQerVKJ8Wi/ebHdgnhSxxbUC4kr4@gtNiCa@Z8v9t9Aw)

### Brain-Flak

Since `#` starts a comment in Brain-Flak I had to remove the braces in my instance of `Num` so that the second one was not commented out.

Answer (score 5):

## 175. [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 8989 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'# #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92*/
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(        7 >77*,68*,@'_        7 )(22)S  / \ 5 \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλiiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz(coding=utf8 1P''53'S^'  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111x             -x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/112\ 
#* 36!@`  e ++++++::@           /"78"oo@    h#115 o# dO           x-----
#comment -[af] tAtAtA TbTbTbRtRtRtVk-VkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkMbMbMbPSPSPSpspspsQhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzTcxxxx8=,  
#~==++++++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.  
#`<`===============================================================                                             p
#<<<#>>]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>x>-]^>[  
#{  
#cs}  
#2""/*\*  
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++9999 9 9        L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt_Z_*.9 999 99 9999 9                       _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L_9  
#R+.----._>]| 9 9999
#--++  
#  
#[#[(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0fx4O6O@ 0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0   )000011100\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q[puts 59][ exit]" ,'_\['];#/s\\/;print"24"; exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2")and(9)or 13<< (65 )>>65or 68)-(0and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and(4)or(95==\"ar_\"[2]and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})  ){}{})>)(({})5){}x{( <(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({;}()<()()()>)wWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU s '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]* *]* * *(<\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'#\\
__DATA__=1#"'x"  
#.;R"12"'  
###;console.log 39; 
#  \\
""""#  \
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[( )] )}{\';     a=$(printf \\x00) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo $((19629227668178112600/ 118248359446856100));;    *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#( (((') )))#\
=begin  
#p            +555!/2+55x%6E2x !|*****[*[?]828+*+]@[*99[?]*]****|!
;set print "-";print 89;exit#ss        <>
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*s     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
#  
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCisajjappppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  ++-------+
1  x*|$0011 \|
51  +|/1000 /|
1  x*|\ 0011\|
34  +|/01 00/|
15  +|\ 0011\|           ?   ?@       _     !
1   *|@ 0110/|          ?@    ?
1    |      +|            +   *
1   !+-------+---       ?  !  ?
1    !                   ? @ ?
<  <    <<   <  <
< B=  =====  =>8 =
, 8= > B    = =
=  ==  =    = >   8  =
D B+  +=   D  x   xxx x
` `  + =   >  8  = >
 x ~   B  =   =  = = > ~
 B +   =  D+  ~ 8  = >x
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x+   xx   x + +  +    +    +
x    x xx     xx                +++   +
x+  +x +x     x + +      +  +
 8=+,  _         +    +   +         +
   +     +                +  +    +
 +             +  +  +      + + +    +
   +    +      +           +
   +    +      +          +    +      +
   +           +            +
   +      +  + +            +
   +       +   +            +
          +    +            +
# +   +                  +
#+     +     ++  +     +     +
#  +      +     +
+#
  *   +
  *+*

   *************************************************+
# +  +
#          +                                       +
   +    + *
         *****+
# +       +
#   +        +
  * *
   +*****
#        +
   ( printout t 164         )
(exit  )  
#cepp  
MsgBox(0,"",169                     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<  
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run         (putStr"159"   )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #"6027"1,_ye do{--}gibe16"124"&#8+*sizeString tnd xfmain=971796los*81''TcTc
More 91 of this red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(d) #d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b    ){  puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77"  );}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<W
>instance Num B where
> fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer}
>g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[w|]
>x=1
>y#a=128
>x#a=174
>main=print$last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"] --}

#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");   print'(''72'')';end!" );main(){    puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end                     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
$'main'3x             A=AgRA;       AC
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /
reg end="";print(85);reg s#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#xxxxclou"78"<\++++>/<~#class P{function:Main (a:String[]  )~Nil{83->Print(); }}
#endcOmment
#nocOmment   outtext("155"   )
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8    \ @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3           \=#   print(size([[1] [3]][1,:]  )[1]==2?158+4:17 )#>say 27#>>>say 170-3#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|   <esc>dggi2<esc>//    $}<}}<}>} [<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}     }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9 "25"   +/ppppppp  ggeeee*n*n*n*es*s^*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1rcxtJkiD4Wbn3D@5LMEEJmQSQePANEJAgiiyxShLZJCVVNQhRiUQCSDGRicoESEAUy2b2znrnsXa329M71ttzO9U9t2c3Zrcfxnb3zHZtxuzMbr@uzY@o@Th2dv0P@tw9Il94kFT3jO2BBDIyHh4eHh4eHhEeES3d7/3mNyn8sCPXnnRtd8iGpj9kbc@6ND2NPZ2wJ7rlr5dWJQlj1b3uqG86Q78spViRMcsxrDa8s6F7YTrWR9MD/xJjA8/tenqfDXv6kJm@oQ9Mn7mj4WA0ZG5nfrJVxvb67gcrhyn7ltOFaEPTG3jmkMLXGHvt2Hq/1danQtanMhx4EO6zZ6b9qf9pyAy339edtg8xNxh76Xq@ifEN0/ddTL7J2HjPNKaAbkFU3bPcF/VXX0wFbTP2BaCoD2xzzPSWP/R0Y2i5DtKkwE5evT45mkpRLLI3p/v7074l9lXOddj@yLiYDlplrz1ft/Vp@GusPhq6B8Np/3VW75qOzkratlaaDtxgTz09mYSq88hz2yMDST3smYABVk/Hsk1fMiB6jQ0EU2joYCnmmXqbR5M6rscwCetf2MxixmDAWrbe0wxmWxB3v7DFTKxN9hHC7Z7PxoM@860@QPHdvhkvrs8c02wzf2AaVscyCANmjoem4wOmvsYsIM@VZdusbdqQIELLyAIwNvJjXhwJTWq7EoOPMZgqRPi2bEIcxwwIYQ6gspEQLvIGUCWgx5WnDwaAJNDxBBAfWn1gZWuY9pmp@xY2Fkjim06baDgIm5HLdCdeSnZpQWUCviOPYPumhxWhEVzWMz0TQOohIytXnjUEEiCJ6@zI1D126pmmmmxSiSwhMxdzGGJBNKrCnZ303uF@GqqSp9D0wVBKeaunP/pS0plWZcvnFfhWZbki7b16xq6Xz9DNWxBU98BTdJVVv2N@/uzMhO@42Mp3vRsJoEpAFZvl3cEwr@cGgGBuCAjmdXSiK3dZ0gZ2LGO2M1UXMQbjsdpQG@zAYW@yVDJj5HkoJSKi6hdQaNt1ukBPKKw3cpAeDtsoQBUYLjTyLDMvgWrQqqiO3Cui8GnPgkrzsUpijYDLOiIoSDvgPUHRIF/ftUcUD1L6Q2RAoAokRYgHHfaGdXTLxiQQjqA41p7pj@whphk5bax5kGVmW2MBGobbxkh99xKy0wEoeUB76sdaISEFkaEiXCoqBv3wL/6s3e0CnLphuF5bsOsb1nYNkso6IQuijiHDuo5uE1oQL4u58@SQwaVuW219iNk7E5EFIUG5Xrkju81cyNC7sqBp9fRLaI6djmkMTc7kXJBnWV@/4LLD4pwLBe/rLahYyoDypmLn2JNdqCXDlFLEM7n@aNjZYrnBHkv7@XfK47LyeOnMBORUTV1Zzue7FWA4bYW84C19G@e8qSdknT/UfddqS4PJsOc6JZYzmGxU3YHpKOkEjHQ27bXSqoYyTVErVtXQOpbTVtI7wIs1yDitVoyq0bDKzcpU8niWAOYKwWBzNRVDlSUQOdQoLvN93XK0wYS9yQlXLMz1z5HkGKzFvJEw036X3CNFHRnypYsMAnJI823THCgFraiimMB4c8uNAfNKOgVDFLhsNTPpVDoTLzpBgJImCoqN9dRyUWzZgx72YUAUxx@A@PaQdw0duMdHKT4EbSLLWsTXJPpBspBMvDLTnslaIEgDPqImyZscps@hoBQQoiaUbMlmO9aQQQhAWx76M9LYdq8gQ8IJ@y4QHQ5mqnehaiAxL0idF4TnRD7JIl04IFAQWstkW7mWBY0AmxvIdMHzsbJB9NUSjwPQeCOJyZ6@PgEoBu8LowbDrA60pT6IB2/CDBNlDggfk3comMmI2p8P@hNqUoVcaX092cZmmtjQy9dzPwYh/TF/a0vCwtcTKgL0PB3zitm60x3pXVThHEiiG4Y5GApBBSXxhyCKpvsb8syJzlPze9Lyk@m8qRMR3WosDxTyvPZEV6ijdBFKXM4GYcp0oYaytuWBWLIn07lDhMupzOX3GCWBwHt5AQqBBgBMZo5NYzQEqQYMfNWzjB7wLGLncLnIO6Hp7MErnjtI9lwnzBqRKdYelSQtH3ohGgtB5LBGZ@FA54qgagkPqvy4x@2Qdb8/B7AboggdQcxXy@sa8N4dMPuu484BCoQMwWKUZAivB9DETlALhI4rULuosYaqYVhFUGcgNaDlA//1hsOBX4Z@whr2Ri0NOCV/6k0OhocOMkt@6E2socvdLdttgVj2oX3mgxzyxqhljacKRH5hHX7wpUtQwDo@q0LP/e0IuE5Jd3wQmOS/i5FjQTIJbgLBf2WISJE0IJTS8UkU74NQOZk4hiJr1JQ0aHRylsnYcGUVHJgqpMuu20cpxN6SYoCaHqj0ltMBaSVkPol8fW5XF8p@0uvSae2DaznKdXppaSldTtdAsi8tPQbXDroeoysDrsfkypEL42noohRZcmFog1KgXzN90wggj9UmVtsYe6WP1kDRG@XyajOrN4riWcKnCqIOJBvEzuED4KTVahWdqirXrqCgWquTLP0uSucTw7MGgghf6pc6fxdUWCUyWP2B66ECW8FO9naa9Kse9IKgtBo9xUufNQpnzbPrs3bm7CadxdRqRa@2oFCQn9LXup47gu5SbayVc8WmqjZWoZNsVdOF9IqibOVsyEhX1Ydbakbn1FbSJkht5ewsDUQV9GkYPY/gjbMlVQ1JBXhgxww6oZLWrrcg/5baVDNpSKumszDEqKbTQBkDieBToZEziUD7wIC7Jy8So8j@BYhHZvg26hI5j6sT8Jpf4Z5teoQqU5kdkMrpQH8JKEB32Q6HNo7r5JwRKcCknbrxjGgQhjHIDzsPFIxWIg4C7lhj0PCh4U4CTQY7YFRmdmGY59qm9pZ0C5kB5zNsr9pcdeaI9wua4UeVCIoLOAe2bkDLTII7k9kZAARGzefnh6iVGcDTug4NS@4qI/QMhu4g/doWqd0jy@8heUE1wrGA1wGqos4NnbtJVDtgBnTaXaC0ObaGXAkHRjjBJM91X1FR7atztQm1NezyEalgyE79sWvAgMWErh9D@eiP7TmXluc6SGRtD0ADx1awDqaAzyMvsFG9flB6tpi@84ADxWa8izHaxqFOE9fwDZZ3XNvtumwFIiBrahpn7APHABRAaRvC@JD51kciUL3rwsglyYMm9tc@KnnFjdVQfdYxZp7iax9AWLD5hY4iLCjzycGP90DEF9cLBcA/eCvQJyxkDMp0GdHTYFEE0Wyh6Z/2RqZkGj2XyWfQQZZqLN82L/PY3GToiXqg6eVAmzI90iXCZGJ2Sxq6I1BK2qZt9a3hAc3N2A72vFGvEoTuAntFAI4scygJdTnqjHGaJhKUTpfH3xujPPUlk57s1eGzvfOj@unzqpwf@V7etlpQf23zvA96k236MmMpdmxCapHg44V97LrDKlUJzgjNflIYKYj/4tn5i4Onx/Xjb3g2lM63@iNbx8x4/BN6D9gkNp3U8dx@qCP6grbLq0hNMzHDiAMmEbqGoSMxvxjz30D/Ps4ZaobUNQyWc/lr6CkibmJEnEfUjMFA6mYyGJPmFUNPEXOLQOLcoua1As9t9AxnFWNqeBzcvPDFiQTk62LhBoH7zsgfxEp2XSyS/@Ww08F@JPQukfdFDsCAAhl6r5I3n5VMZBWQZSZobuQQ3hrB47OZc@HNBM2NHMJb5/BwFnQ@uKmQeVFDYBsEDGdN58KaCpgTkbPlKcjoFy7I4xeWTzPfcT6Vwo7/TJID7SWhpMhRSCmaRWC5y/nTH3IcEDUZYPILF5XmyHUOQ/11hBKC6F/Ysyk70HXRTyLqDFKzIbyp9lsd@pkToSxG1iB3cH4XqfIlzg7i4N8FRcK8omg0RiBgQC3L0fPH9MDRwjx8kuOeBDItszOCPjYPShy674iW296imJ1Wy1oUFeiCqAfPOdG8UWse2WDM0psZGrME4Ycjb2ibbfH8r7/XhgqYrZ6ePiG9InScA92INzoLa0skxRf6mV@zFOfDyLZ0IgO57gJp6DgbqduhYz5o7CJYLtfTvT5236JygTnxB0TQLXzGMfdMe9Q2g@f8TIjEyQE4T@1YfSoRPFH/pPHEguRT0wc8PWlwtqu3CQrXsywzqm1eL@aYaxwx3QSk/D3wDEb5LJpWh@HscMR/cSb9rnq1BvidT5VykskK63qraOZdX29Z5i184OkXo7abG1x0qdCI2sYibueNCAeluY6tX3DnOTrnE4AX0bO6XRiMi@eiaFc90KP8AWhi@St63MIqQT/HSBnRb4Pp2fx3UZRgnTJ0LKaTZdPP5zAksYgBrQZJi2tcuRiZrCnC2nprgsPJ3udzFmZICgQInqqRyRRWsQsL50aj1bTBYHF67Pco/fb2/NR84Y0AGG6nY5p3tWbokay@budK7ZhzoXAOJjsi15yopODnDFv3gUmGgszmJVQL/dzGuNjJGMgukesWto3QCaa@F82iRmkGluHalj/gLUm8LJKS0/NPERhcXqWfKCm@zdK3DaMY7MBzoWt@Q3eNIc5kLuCjewguPomI07QxxtDcRbQz3Cv8LlQdeu6lyX/nd2Yf52J1DxGUs4kzLGNO8rZxF7viWhj9zKfixVyshoY917/MXrqu1zMdn5W0QjDrggsRum3zWc3Tg8PFPO1btuvDAAh/b6MFDHR8n//O5@Y42SzdydHcUtw9P5lAasA0MRRfUJm63XXtja1uXoefhTU@8joo2cXzvhItlEjF4p0SKVR8XKcongtF@QX838UMNH/l4UR1zHlLPzpPfIkJzsUFhOEBrj7NL9x@YYtSank@Gl1UAZ7Ru9InwfO36C0WUTfoLQYTUptBr8ME21vgGHpclf5tclu7Pbf2/WTSDNjNuwoRq9wL2wQJTb8zVcpKheJnpigWCveXUB17ZI7MuRLjsPXBRDuhW2TF/ZEqiGIsi5mZPBAP52XCWB/FoPBeWGP/jW@3ChjdtqCR36m9zJV3A9C1BziOPgLHETpmE3ad0SBRuTHaHY@c49sp1xsELdttJ5DEkM@VSFt360gJddw36btIdd/ruzD0dfugMzj3qH8BlKa6@G8CMPlEkD9YOC3o3Qq3zMIVLdBXQf@AWrUu/BzOLd5P8JQWjdkp8vY2jMocczjB30XUnidIW65rf07tgDxtW6iWgbKJJmt31dKMriMWN1k0O@HjTEers2hegvc1YgAJ1MPB8sKKPoIiDalzuE8tz8xl3tJrxWY27xpHQo9Nkz@@ZwTuRfgeY@Mualva5q0Ic3XUbZm2zh/jjbXb4G1rq/dRiQaBnkuT2zghzqfAowWZ1JQIGkyAWFY75xs9s2/S6y1Kvt7@MPKDx8JIYxe/c4K1PM3@Lkg3sKDNO/ibmG6PaUVD1zH9/FD3uiYOT2xcBRG@i@RsMKk8l7gHfb1r7t/JXNHsA1q@0CpjzDl/HqLMF6MNSHaHJOEjP9e5MCd@8JyvH08MqM9R/1Zo89q5gZOcdzZsLT93Lv0Otc/puT2nZ/Y8ahzh26LmARw55EbCtxUC8O/p/gWa@pBMioZ1PT9OXdu17ftQF2Uil5CuO3/@dQ9ta9uQ9LPgTvQWBIjHnVN10HUTkagPX9R2euYIeijfHboDM0dvi6LaOKnDf@dPKR8cpn321jK9Nl/mxBk@fWi1bJNdWYDCBz@@XDh/wqhluzpak92ixANlgud9pqAM17urV@jq7nAwoMf5wB759EMzubnO/CnKMtsnRO/DC9aQLzBzjjW7bsvoWXdVXsvUh451kRetX7zO5/KkLKaCWyz3DL012wJSeRMNeaAaDz/Bx8H8dm@9ECb@t@ojuyPPm9wtG5KLp@GsKl8LQMei@RexKDYnmHp@tKIIrAVuWZAQa2gLGYp0adSbc2YBlJPiwtmghMWHIIG9ujq8g0qGa1zcqU4snJ8U661IKsOKrQqD//Qkxu1oPBfiDQaHyvNR11fvij9BVeuZ1ec7AHQ7snW6I2W9yzkHF5J8272KTTSDSNAd8ZjLeaUXd7cnWg1Zv3VhpMyKL87rhwd3AzNsa@DzX5brlOaqELNrqvNy/Aar8HbKnEBL6Nx/8NB3PTSPBW0jZ3imb@AkOApqLkC5eHLcLgjsnM2iyEHcuWWZXc@dp8YkO8Pc16/Mro7WNi8sNLyx/dn@ESBPL@3eB/CPRrpv/WjkDs25MKeXeO8D8qXetYzniSmKqBP/sTnoTW6V2XzN@Jg2NYTmr35W7MYAP8sTtvd@uMElRQYyZAwbGEeyFJrojrDxDl1PYxRPUfRMRlUlnginQbsORAti0RYDND/muxd8Zlv@kOJaHdZosOXrcblQLt6wKpPLMms2OVQyhN0bD2hvwDFP2ljWm9XldC6XXk6fOWVWSFNU0/bN@VH1RLyORQ@OZ1R05ujc/AndQUkr3Kza79GWBejo2tBhvoZhFglN1@PGwdzy/BTXU//LX7bFTg5Qqn3Wt6B1ASFw95HbN3vu1WOer8i9PhjouBMEYVz1sDfG3HO7deZfYc/KN3C4V@z1/umWMAsXe6Tg5Qi7gBgWvFJxhIc2YUNeaRybtmtythAZh6mCQhmuPeo7oMq0hz1fg9ZM5l4jLzJzARdGc4Ye6nPtLDtgbRNXrciKj4YwtutekD0tYvJf/pIbw5Mtn7CxCrKnTTCxHNFkr0gW6IbhjgDrAMhH03NFFAWJDG1lhBMEwNQm91fRwo2s9IETc4GNOmbD7dR36ycst8fSuIkLLV8rVkdZrh9/8aZRaFa/Y/28@V9/L69eC7rJD3PbG76cZUGUyg3yVTx4HYKj0DSTl8eyKBZuF6LdMSFTiS2JCrqpugKb8z7tNCK@M6/I5pwspRwUBbiFBzomH5TooUqgeaOpLisjPhTNnQzZOu50g9GdDi6@N4ks@NB@GpMsj9kn1kNeyRloVQZvnCA2muz3q08Da4TVuM1I/pnZGtFC6WVJK61WqTjL59WdGrk8s@3i1pnGu7NxqZA7G2/uNfN@QJyzs/HDQulroJ4LWvLyozw2oL1Xz66XtVrh0ydfnzBZvklXuBEMtPLl66ODo72T0/rp6xOg5g0vbGrf9fp6JCmQF8hIrufatCcJyOJZpn@39AglSPgG0RWFLetsB3dSqqoUtxCjqILUck5e5s4wCgwX46nvSD4vvW/GwmcjCMnUsZiQouyIGEnwTNqPS9BswFtYL9jcQakPKYImRnNEIdFIZlWgUg6odE8asdlS8hp8TB5QjXcT6nYY80AAraIYsxGQSGFeWF4ezgs3t/A3/wAlHkC/9ruWmGDcWmKMcVuJIWKUjFLs1w9evD7eSyYCdoo2oMKQ3MNtzR1qW3wrG@cuV@yaCiQTjWZ9sUsilK0@u7R8Gu0iv3WwZ7BBuGBzJHsJH6ULt6lmddsHSd5ug2hqTYYo2UCka2T7xg3gcg6TU0AsLexos0yWMK5fnd1FA5LrygAp9p4nXqZ4BNmX5mz3OzPzP/yLP@Nb/M6G4P5D4R4XnsLbH4u3Drj/eRBSLMLbvwzfSvD2U/72Lo@knN3XxEsTEhEJ@ObgiPk0IEcS9fVxrPTYt2HfaTkwJLT6QOtLIh1G58WKKBPBURpvgPJQXUB2FNIolyk/02squCulnM@jKoKzqBpZaZljPhynTSrfjnBzJnQl@Y31jbUijEfN3GUAkAzNu2gWxAGqahm4Urq0BtX3LYPt7Oww2Td026xuVDjJ88v6u1X5fYjoMsSVuNbSYJAGkkQpIKwmkinLeqaoYlJsnOlimjUroJDwGoQ@TSEHRFHR2wlslaHTdAWpgD0cczwkwT8JtDFQhRwylTX5Ft0AUA4Acdi4hXCayyNDH7SLjPG9Fq8G@S1GO8FoZXkekzXesbPhmdMUW0kZMMwv57CcA@4/mrO/NOSe@uzGRmV6WyKWhj05cVw0CNsHbJlSypdW88UNNdamZAEK8MUW9AlAQpuBNmiY1gd34Nd39w6@PDw6mdmgRzHT09HSLF3byZzltGyjGTrSU1wfEPXpfv7k5dP9gJRxrKL1FIwRLapMozkvt2lMF@T@lltYzeZNATMZFQv3BUyTArl9WnechR6F5mMRd7kFyEyuinp902ju1M6c1Ez2n@ZtWk5pK8hc4Drzactyms2ROQeB3dgpHnTha4GBcUmOtuSHRsX8PfJevMUuPDYj2mcXWKhJtIUg3EEgaQts16DsWp5nRZvMOGIBviBrAlSLiGqUoSHNrInFsWGiLLMnfAjr6pBIh3wgS3uHdQfGMJ5l8Ng@CWg@3KUNrzDgORhGYyQYd@FEEA0FJzTsAVERTkW1LRqv615g6B6GnJh9K3ca4IOCI9o3JzaMwXi@Z1util5tjFlonn3b9jHNH9jWUMG9bGMNh5NQGkXFAhR3cDPYWN3Zbop9dyzYHpehHXZHI6DXkTtg0RD@mRm4jmEUx56NADiwgcm@HPUhXocexyb2EiZ75eYgMdAxHSDRwD1logxav70OuWs9c9y2utDTKGoWRNLDYjHam6fj5jInDXKYk@oLNBSKE@az9hPGKKY3dM1y2uZYwW0w5SZSB/zTV28v06o8wwO0qVHs8WtP724MhIU@FK022hk4JRC2t0NBkGw729taz5fQfB5GIJDjydB7AU7oQ5VOXx8wZUTbQ32mMXpVzhQn6w89leVq2J9dMYdlMjR2gQcFaIxSdshl2Tgbr@BpCkq@CvWMvr7TxsdHa8AaRU1rgpsyUdkyzj7sgrqB43ZVAtUUkpQJLHTA8FdGjK5glIYY8ecyZSvRBi@INTeYGnK3Rw0QaEGlZrVH0X6iWAvkVN3eLovaSIrDbQZssTNHYgDYOWIu0E2BvsIAGqiGQgxi7cKg1AKB8uQr03GgvSrAM31onUwfAZN5ajY4YSgbnRJBOaQ4is@FRTUgmjw9Yi99bbugzyznKzQCrtxAv//@DDv@juj6J/n/Pq/lK9fKsl2d5EEZU2vKcq9azKyuZDLLzoqy7KA68ugRDpxvlkHbOddkTR5DpNyyrVaAn0E7qi47lWV9R1luV0srlAJeMxn1GhJ85@e162X9Jr/8CLSJLPh4vHUqyz5t7CxoWvEG8MMWspzPAs9c4wZHOjcIs1@2MhnEQVs@RwS@y5@dZKhfOTvJ0xi9IpTcfLcfiJGkrhLWxMx5R5yAwrscSvR1lOhi1fw8iBw/O2JO2K3a9VdoY8RoPcT0/Th/JUPuL1iEQEPhJISMwnfWAgHHChARX7O6qoIw@c1vUsUNGPU93lhV3Mzj9UIlk14vVtIplnoCamp@Rfbk67NnuUtm5tKNjr6ufds8ujg6@lo9U9g2S6d2D@XimvyObZdW8lIqv1L4tJnPv3//HhRi1qhpNa2pNnLpZkMJBnWbrLa5uZLd2FrJPkmfR76qUiqpJ1BV7Iyts7NNXV/JrJWeOBUI28bPKiuCE3@34Ftk6@tsDz9/@x//9ud/@zP6@zl9/9qyrIHfbsPX7bEL9hE@Fx2G/@T@2I65dXS3Oh8VGGuAClql5lE8SqfXV9Mn79KMPYbPEvzRP3zCV/xdIh/hTVFmP0tSqmakPqaKxWJqQn/n6C6OEzv4cvQ6XvTJF4ulMyalVtjqxtIToK0JwhQ/5fKTGJS8vLkluy559SCXdeamWPswFmOcw4@UCo5DyTX0TpMN6/jHTlv4dzzEvzcXuTcXby6ODfx7eoF/L1v4d3SCfwMf/37Uoz8P/547@Nf6Fv9efMS/UwNR36pmGWD@XbXKMWYC89nPvABNOw9cCOX9zvvq7/Zhn/MZSCkY@aVqtWYmd3PT0N5lKhXxDzKzEr7hh7sA3@ZNLrfzrpbJNAjvRk0UYCfXrPHS0K92/m4HwGZ2Gjs72nmtNq7lmu9qDSzlNf4Y/g0@SrKcXzlbQWd1vHPMQT4LYGLDYPgnPi94Po2jFzDYOc2WdnKp0n59N1s6ef00VYS39egVA1fx9Xiv/uzwNcQ@erFXP9n74uDN3usj8Peb57UnTzIaMMwTQLnWbEip8cNMLVMdDofnPz5f0bCf3Obd5XYMi6nP@RwXf5VSz2rj1/ncDqD94nwbC3lM@eWAIs1PjAOWUrkc8g3ITPg2Ug0l8zjzuGAXLgvFi@LFS/cw@j88HEOANS58cL1Cr9ArtqGpsYL5ujApTMaFvntYbIPThL9CH5xWoTMudAtOwSkWJ@MEqMX//UN3@PLQBWgupByOC0MEDJDWDjcOnzB47R4evgSwHUDhA/xZhUJhDLiOC5fwX7CL9Hl3XgAiqLgLGt4KhbMzqcHk9yaIT62Y1gppbSOdtprrG4Nvz65vShvfNkjhW99uNmjLe1Nm2fT5WSPdrKTy/tlZnkt7ubQmVyjCzc35@bP6af38PI8TZeOd5cyTTO4JfKq1zI54PE61a5XHZ@UccmXAn6n8zuOz2moO3RsZqI8S@O3kM5/5iUDCs7Z0JqWVq7dv3@L37dXlFXeRg/udvQ1D8edtHry4C73gg1Hz89InHeNZJlSUxnrz@gZ6vbN0JS36RYXR@RJy8Wxc6rCSjGMPZVsF1aO4igruxjpTa7WNdfDY2FJzSgHHJjzJmTwYDM5kjWZjNDK5rVbrnqdPcASmrAEQZXu9Wj2Tde/8TG6Umph2Pbe9wVwvt72qyqr6rrizA3lgFiUVvOX0WHa9NLu@if8p1zc7Cn1U/FNV9FSBcehZUxWIoK7D2/haYTvKjoJ@4IXprm9q6KR41@BqKGpTvbnhfsp15UZRdzjYmgqUY6B3/CP9Qy/0/5//l6@ZD8rLTQoVaoetratKa2KqaxvKVmZb/FWXgLKKvJpeRU0pracbjScrqyuba43HzRW2gl@2ouyc1Zrzu2w1nYIGHTTAajGFtYsCTKscy8WSnEZ3KlUxxLEatttlq9sVknKQUIYPuqQ0g1qt7YR8HHXlag2ZgFG1MrXJ1Jtr4G0KA71bEUtXZ2fjQkFllVZ1@Tql31QQK5ndyCJm0DoItJKu0LqmfC0v616j2JRv5OXr1g0OTlaKKuml62uVysoady8rSnF7o7RdKm1ubGwVN7dATdkoFPKsWNwqrW2trm@vrW1srW@AcFPVCmW4UlwRcAoARzi3KhXT140KCq1KCvBQFBgGAt1TZ1K1ZXYhe6DLIN6eM@vr60v5EjzGDzf2SmO29GkFP40VqJ@t0lZmJdN80ljZ3sbqamLIpyWpgouKfAVTzslcCLCtbco3hcsf/LNTkxr9cadJm8aruUZxY72ZY1BZH8adFUCjuLmaWuGxzeUjkm4rz2BUlCnC/96STx3VgDkw9t0ssLZr405Kt9NZAs@e7rOWacIgz7Tt4AwXGIfa7SurbS5Jvgmf/pFujkzzajS6MsPPruXrHz7oA/qMOz/88ic//PJ//OFXP/3hVz/54Vc///X3P/8JfP8Svj/lz5/@u@11/P319//yf/vhz38Fnn8N3/8M3//06@//9e/xL73/DXz/r5jf34hvLB7/SgDrj3/9/c/@4tff//NfwPffiO8vpr8//Om/5///t/hD569@@NO/wR/x8pOfApX@/q9@if8/@6u//8@/xP///X/9@7/6V3//x/@WHH/GHf/Pv/l3/Pfvfv8nf/dP/@Tvfv/7Bb8/ufX3@3v4f/@P4HN/PO8D5z7l@lyf738rfH4XakS5AA8Ap/3RD//6D4BX/5S//TN4g/8w6A/Dl0QIf/nD6AUg/C9zEv3Rr7//k78I3/4gGTERBkD@EML@PBH2hz/88vd@@Iv/4Ydf/tkPv/xjlEO5te1sPZsr3j52SEHE9XvEw4gb94kHEXmUJbYkleiJP8KTLZFrvCKtr@IQK8c/Ge75aRl1THb2SVqH98ynPJ6@w/KfROgZ7mkqQujqGoUWQGUuYOg6vgahMVRw4frxk4RWzxFZ@QT6Lyiz@VhsHvExR1T4Zz4lhDmmpPClEHH4RpkthemX5hDmMXsCwdBFUi@5g7/4Aj5PYbwnhn3V2harSlm2VcXDSTBiFd4pHJ30Dh0qnl1dlZ6xpzhQRe9nQCE@NGdj6T17j9iif41HZTUJwr8Dj6ccDEFDUN9J4JXhPs/g@Z2IP5YIHv4LPRXd@A0C4CfDuB@8ZhBIJiATy0g8Bg9mwSNOTRwsYTxMN8Z/FgEScDISECKTjQ/JwiwykZcUvmZmcgnxmQrLRGGM8swkQWXYDMDbAhPe0nRCNheKwGBh6FQxg9A5OQahqdkkYVCcQJlMkmCYMlmojJRBE7kVkelKZoUsYlY@9yNwogzmkuOWT5zeK1HJ43Aj7COohC9PkKG4Ud4EUeG6FS0psOLGWghYlRQ6o42pNLNhDkCVk1763afuWClkZTlb3Jg/eaDiPAjE/cYtl6vfFdc2JXjS@wiPixMHlwFv4xng2g58AA@pdp1DISDVTvZOIez0kBVLBY01Cs3rtc3S2vraeml1Y2N9s1Rc29he21jfWi0UCxuF9VKpCArr9tb25o1U@5qNNXZ09KMcuMe5XL6EAFm1uL5ZmVQhIXlJNVIRuSI5uc6BDokInJHOeo32CziJc02zew/gw6QHEnsAXvABwDiNy8Ty2cFhRSyyoKldqJjzFRe5uL4tEz3OTKfNAUuD2Ec6xZNfXwEgoITDXqDV3dBlp65L5909NY0FMXZ7/Oz2Xc/1/d8hzlPdueBBzyw838UYhkHPddzl7fetYW9BjNeDPtr0mt4/GoS9fgsQxClPHuEp/Hi2686LsMleHy0o5cvQWhvXZshcG6IfH3zx/DT2PN2r7z6XNtjTw1fPph7rItI6e7G3fxq@bvLQIOl6COKbvRcvpl/FA8cyS2x9M5vVNA1@8JmlDz215XdBlKK2WKeQNwqlTbmYPZ@YMFK5zuVuulbLLG7AEHVNfpSCcRSeG3jCT0YcOm027hDLb28WN7c3bNdf2Sqm06fGqSG9RHuV7SI3NLZ8tKgEkFcOGbS28PDl0WCxJzzQC52e1e2BCLlywwi@719dhdNEb4M5oXBu6C1r6Tp@P/cDOZjxz/B2jyHPg/xmQuzZ6NJzGAP28ZBB3Fg1xDUSq8MKkobyolTa3lrf2l4tbWW3trfW1mGYuZ4tlrIwjt7cLmSLheJWEUbP28Xs1tr26hpIJghd396UUiADrE4@D/K3KMv0tBwDj3XawfOxXK1Xk1Jts4NMy8ZKW2Wpdugx2mLy6tZZgUFCWUIjuJVxVS6toXngapEVZUnWmcFS@/u7hf19WX6KLzhHuVuQ5Ta@rG8VCptPZdmkkF2QniVI1MO3vQ2czJRlC1926/v7COEDvpS2EIYsX/AQ/mIHL5sQzcGX1VUEwGT52xBcAYC7HKMtSjXkL4XC011ZHnH0tuAP4tX52xohu4cvGICJ9nnILoTJ8hdBIlCCZfmYxxNZPQ/KW6/L8gF/qdcRxJdU@HVeqK/wpU4fSOTBG3CuLHfB0fVgfC/LLXAi/8qyAS5jooNfH1y4ldQZ6rI84eXAksjymGLrxoUsnwf@kA/g8/y53hu2zS7/TDz@NCDoAIKs8Whvv/XFF61ut@VN6ntfHFPQl18@1z9MRl6r2xIJW@fwcTEVBF30J9MfE4POz3V7ftBXEORMBZ1Pzk3C8Fz/FjATny5m1D//EoO@hKB5k2MCIHz6ELmFn6d9eD7VWzwo@FAQPcetllxBlsWm01GIcfUsPehMS/WaoXmCr@iPSXaVUW65HdAvRltqbv3xaEve2JTLK/CUH8ur4ISmwQrpAmNy@kyW1cZ287G8uS6X048f59KPio@ZvLktl@XNTeh51coNij1Fve4o4@y4WgCPfH4HGzQ2QXiCLiB68lNzPNSem7gubuRybxOfHfq8hbi4hwU3Irwa9WGccIUKDOgXePxmYA55Xn3KipuFioO7eEx8XR6nxlKtrQ91GNk8vR6VyyIu6CjdagNhfMKfnZz8tvZWbrJ49uubBUDutWOUNnd2GlefmqDXVItSbZLSq8XSFryhY3MtrtMs27o/XC5ulsqN0XIjV2wuLRU@dXfkH9cI@I0UFp/LtVAyQSD0Sgy@uZyE4YOqqA@ZKXhwMK6u0Yq8kk5vltJpNV2BtEsyUFoQmhbgsEKD@pBBIkJ9bJcguWcOR9AvFyo3Mzl7F2UgrYcmGZRDmckboDyBN57GPO/zBAbf2fJKa32n9k9mPv/dP5n3me@LH4krgxtFKXUjtfGYqrVtKXUt3Vzf7NSCHL9ik4meCQa47BFj3cyytJzGoqdXkyO6erXePa4Hs7X1XSmVW3XX3NTy8rKU2jmtyavyoXYeLs7U8rQGeIZLhLiUpp2d7yxlfquVm5xWexKsgALqeckzcYdCG6@54QsoW@tYFV3mpzK/5QcykaoAU6rghLecQulg2O4IV7J3zniBdr5L0QILO7rujBwyUSu/RF1Z0ctcM2k0oYl@98qyr7dWczWyrFCAx25uiC@MQ1rsllKOK5xASBilDKGhKqBar8tiqGGywcn2u813W@9evj58fbjPnhTKW@UtpPsZcEm2mC6moRKfQDdsHe9JqcEnd734nfNlJVUepFfX0quxajurpgIeV5D1lUaj2GSN1WazAcyG@MJ7tVp6XFzfyqyVi5tMTdVwH0lpE8mNLmj8udVUM8WBrG2q4KYJ81IxVcsL7@JmUU35Of4GSdZTvpTaevkeJ1iC61isErnyZPC9fLNzA/@1G9bY2bkheXQjHPhzc8PD4Z/KEb7xR/SJRYzHicJ/O6bTzlPN73I7/H8Hf3YPeUnljXVZTb2v1oAV3p2/O09JqW0ml6j2MnkxEIKW1EXVa8WhP9Nf8d@t@CuRxwrokivhG7zurLD1WpExcyWfz5@pPyqBXra9vbG1kZJ@AxS7xSAVQkMLrY4JAxQQ5XNMtOqe9VJH8zUnNNMCx8vRRzx6@0lw6U6gwjHU4dAGEZW4uJ/Q62JedFdV0m/i53HDDPpKErosupuNdYgFca1pSBsf2ApukMd9gap0LT0AWCNjSHtt4KciSQ9w0we@KkG8LHvkD1WcLSuo0oMHQgD7Q80fniNwTCQ8c8WKBF0DkEdvt31Gh9/jOinfTKjjFgp3wE@SsSeMJ/LpfHKuj9I@QMw3hvAK63AsoDQrjHIkzLFwPPsHPFpr1EFU9g9e7EEaGE53yFhKpJa9Fl4NQcVb6qgs7EeABng@elVQiqJjRAAHnlzdUPu4Y9Gg5swyrIjhHTK6glhZVswSJlnWEQkb@NqE5Ai@A1LNB8A8d4WXgK2ci2xFGQQ@VAggIZaOukN06F7XyIraw1NWG02VXQf7ohQMZTusFG3cErCgMvh1bpTQ6LfFMffViMwErdjMQtVW@P4aJYwnfCJC3Ugrw2y/wqtqUJG@UgzQilxPqXzXf/TIeDdo9JsVtV8d4jOT6UMXfaFYPMrKsNqvAnsMGlazMmxkMlaz2le/UvAdb5PA/lzodr4qygYld6qACxqx@Wr2Y8PJfec0s/sNJwMoj7IrP65@zOrVAmplWatazNrZb6tFUQ7Ic1j9mHEq@g580fAwsXcJtJKMXkl4YZILxa5@bOhNVPNsSJjJ7ENhAE@/YWcyTRUytyFwNmHFfvRIz9i1ccXO5VSM9W718X5jCI5mporvZUXfGT/@2BhB@rICzypkY6uAPKQTtL4JcQf8KkBjXqcR6hxH0kLHgF6/Wl358eOVH69Ul5Y@Nsa5fjPLyV8uRNyAyI8R@Upsb5iy8mOVTZGElo0V@aFVfqit@EzOWpkMEDk7iKXkGK78GEIGmUyA9Q3KS7pkKjBqRQ4T@5n4yfJ0fjPZqNPx/j7dkjFs485OSFv3DcsS0fmW3IFltvF0TMvP0hUSOsXAMHHrHQaejR8/loKsxRYayBmFS8tkOs4r0N1HHq5j0w2K/DyIu@TrPDEcyNxwPE3XGcDIfXUj1lxJNFGD8z2jgVFQDFwXbipcYvGNUyBsSHpAHJIeGC@HUgSJJOSEiFkVgVBbQQVBKpQTHX6WCZ3agPIJdeuw5YMI4WhAY56DhpX9UCXZBPxkgYtZO5QfOKCpSA@gEIgDlsFqshoIMvboEROvO1VWLG1iX4DRMN6HTBEjzWAKmd8DU4CBWH4AHkV5SJkAbg8wBDcGJjJa@90yEvt6FUiQ@ZDl23s12t6rjByf72pHuqkcDayLBw8@ZKprAiH4p6EJpIewm9@kRHdfZruHL49en@4dv6yfwC8MRLfit8QEN7DN3L80wHuVWpZDm9sM/bhofvOlwZiC4y88jBkvWGyzL1@/YKXSq2dZPEoRSJ/iE@DQoZZDSKZPR9X7mut181fWhZVP3gyLd@HRPjq6hzYXXCeD6FDnbEd77aOt9j5O6kFnLs5/S9zc0jd9X1wrlQuu6KTTd@jUgT5unodWKK6hoi0KgZU12fSjmUSWdop4Vteiexd7HEAiPV3IMeTJqX1IeH0UDYWBo6XtrUKhzApZdBQDRylwrAaOtcCxHjg2Asdm4NgKHNvCUQwgFzlkGCyvrm5Ezs3IuRU5t0PnWiFyRhDWSpFzNXKuRc71yBnlthbmtrFFcFkqoCY1XdPDsOLaVhBG8wxD8lwHMMVpzzVAtDQTE5KvzXhCfltJz83tgsjoIH@IkUqljegdpE8Qt6pwrLIcjyzPmb8JT@irJD7MI4bd8zyQSntjvC8PmE4tM9w7LEl4FIthmzooA@YQtJTqPvC/qZb5mRrepBztH0YI1WL4DsnxuhZIU6QrHzn7zAkuzQvm0EpzofFDSVhImNjma4Ekx7Kc6Gk5xLWEXxzqEgpYpOiCGCUeA@sguVs7yPPUG83NcvX2LBMA52Y5gxSHuz4vFdJGIeDVICn1/wStGuTH9RSTahvUAHHBL/HAVIXi4SrV62JZ/vX3v/g/2K@//9mv2A9//qv/9z/9z@j@9/jzH0BnYaUwwk9/xsjeA37@FSPrDrI0iRJR/NWy/MMvfgmv/9O/ZT/85Gc86E/@Qs6uhYAgBL2ilD//Z/jzB/jzf8rZ9TDiz/@IR8QkcvZGSqhWCsT66V8zBrkhlBDYL/6SMTkDCoYiOK/B23gzdhQDBxCSoUGu5nQ4/8Vr0oDGBTUjA1zxVozeMlgBagy4p@ONtVHbA3WGz2eilDZ0o4fb7YWX66P@Y6AK4/paF/jtqg1Kj5iSSEPpf5@VWTqDcXBiBc@UqXIZLsovyi1HoRg3I@cBO7xqSYCiS@RCTGB4KwF/00hg4ms4bKERaZHziKDvK7wRO@hA5ICz6E4tSeQVpMYpGXG/KF2yFgx1kWmxG@JnstDdYpLYD16MZZgQN1PVBrlM@8CQMTqlIZ6UPMz@AKoEkoX0RsLiC1EhOw0uqjnRbPYO96caDH5aoGJexCVSmFGVyfIdcZHSIr6KGtdqMj7HV0RoFMqrzcSZD/Miy19//bUsxfwKyENeWyEIsUJxkREGFZNBpVhQKRYEOHOYJGvWS6UpHKjjQLmYPN@EJ4uJqGSyiLmw5QT1gGjAWJBPiGY79sjvVWdBk0ROCrtZ4DGQxWZVtJMzh2ROjcnqTAKAmUxTna7L@aALM3FmK2p@SqR2widRW4shJdLEGgVRT5qmUlhzxe15NZfM8BbQxWbmnhmVCr9jRrl7ZrSxfndG09WKaRPgF9P3brETiIlQwkfAeMNPJToo7Bp/AawXiSPE2COnosKQpy6GPK0rlylzLpIF/3xwdnLi9lgvdqIyDmJeuUOTTw88Gbgw5HBRC45dVv1aRE8MO/gt713H9Uw/fpaLxXe7O2k8Tchwuw70alk8w9kSVyOjlQE/Ny7Zr4Q9m9BCd/lN9giaEwo1z/Nzy7GG5@egfNodNSIgvmoGbkFOSwYkBFcsvRKqtocDxcWz6Ifq3TBJ3@XJTi3jQjkciMA0ZFJnMKAzTBsGX6yHl2T6LicJFpFfmwkaaWuo0IGRPbfvdk3HxYOUMPUU@IMINiKkDwaES5bpWWbEMBKDaMXI6qpI@tVnJ2VflfCa1yB9KQkgQYws86ZpjJT15mR3vjA7nizI7@Tz8T2J43tyO74dy/OH0ziTJ8724PPzsl5VIggQMUJj9W40suLstBl0EqiE3nhBM09wbxTbZALVRkzrELUuomsd4I9s@ObTZmOB@JtF9L@9AoPke/etPlJmTyYgb/p0nyoN0fxg1V2B6AeqGtkvxrILWfvZPfMSAx0a4WWZTILLwZ3s0DAHA9PBKz35JwB8B8@j@dMM35NNVJUHzsHJu8yyi9LiKnp23jZtfWK2FREzG4MblPjY1Nskr@5XcBR0JPRcfiu3UsgWE6oYnThCkcoLWEbPXqrqYrbiUayQe2gxjjA8WEw/mribFs04CVrlayCuBxI0RYcS0lGQg8lgwk8psun4sECO8v6H1@QrPLzpToIAHfittcVslK16m/g8VsIi3aNHCONqySLTXv@g23JBG5@pw88j0d0lpVmGMFE1qOWEdrKoxq3bajzGFQFPcq3kfix5F9Pdm@dirMaBRSJs9/O6kBnIu7ptG4YSh8h9bq0x15mRCeiHNeY6C3qV8zkCNUxJkm6Id@dVuX6hShY4D@B5Cc838ESAMAY95wwVlA312mDKi0L6@iCmtQifhoG6aIyKanwdMRZLCtw4kXsT5mkszNOYydNI5Bm2gGSWsUiSkchS1AJWz21VYJud4QLpjEE4cofHbWIbPo6re7j2ep220mUry9KX6TII5LSZLu8pIJTT7XT5GTn8dPmEHBfp8lfgiNpW@lO6HDQLjODBKzmeoL8Q4fhupMu7inojDfFE1iBfLV0O6xTiPOavRJEbPr3aEqv@bjirauKV66hUZhlyjA8PF4vVaGbpW4B/iipO@oXApSorrVBkHIAkOo1Yj8HzgW5Ds90r01PmdR/lYGpKzG9EcygQnqnGJlWQS0Ykj9KpdFIYccQwlCYf4QkIotwsz8eIFWdGZnehI3K38LJ7IHYyf6KeRvpAW6HwBkSOT@LYUfqgvpIgeAXeD09MvAjPGXSC7AgjNAZQ56CFRH2fvqVQWNdTp8by2o/X0OwcAVZiLojCa4nAxmQ66HCom1JmA3eQZBIKxdU@K54GP6JRIvdOJSOpIFrmgmDyFiVDwRBv/OptxYmlQ9QSIggDG4Umb2Vhv0CyGIMiWRfTVHnjAxRiMqdNx7iZyLbPhJPicXGTpb5iUTcUpOVZkuRKiklIrOEZByN9yHOP1mXw5IPPG74GKcd4Ar2CAGIpw1y4fHU/Q393uf4eKNQBEaYymKdYz@9KZ9XrW3vZKcztKNvZCsTALHumzlWOwhwiksPoIKaZ38ZrMyo@XrPMlXyeaQh9StsPyBaOCe6g2/TYgsNCLcG7THpe4MTsRWkxoWY1EvtSC5QWDXMScHjBQ0yjot2OKy/4vCrGEOyj4fHZFewlKzheeQiPCuBNkZy3cm/kkHlV1LbpMK5o5YKvOrhoJRaegRzzBHFP9muhiRZ4HJ4fPzt89eIb6HQ3NzfV2aUIbLWQNurHpVuXCcJhSymLx1jiydtkO9FzveHSmSPPmpSRBygDOq3bcPYTbVwVsiwmz6faLqTjcWMUFbAuomagJ6QSqjo6dtmWoCu/20tZ0QWQQL0FemdptIarRsgduKBzfk7d1/k5Guecn4teDKsmXEb6TUrc8l2K7DXAlbBmIo3LnzkrDicARn3aHxVMwIlT4LgdSgrgHAyD1GGqkTO0AmMHnB@iHZLBWr6yWsTZiYNO6EN4oFGGUlrDIWxpHY@M4akwNk58kmmlyGeJKzp4GYI/cB06zpqOCCW1Ha9m8IOpV0J75FzpZAbCc6GTbmIYcYOsYF3Mdfg9BT5Pi1sxaQo5oE2WmV2NVnxK2zDkuLAG/JTj0PTDVykRIUw2WkDjlm32AaUT4N05s8kvLaiV3r7V7QIj5cWFddzA5VSHpDm3k9sNTu9LsTe6bbWDc@SFTRjd4SDmgYGcSuL4RZ@VNkCb2s4CZaMvEBbNZBgesVggIy2KBd9NeGxy51Y2lnZJmajJZzH4qAhvSTnHmuX73y0PL6e71J0YnenzKT41LRYtSQ7EVi6DA/8kcfJrldYpNbRRGyhySg5OAkQnN5vQbSM4mFDBIzHL0gOHBA9agDGD29aAguug0kbLa2pokuqwh2y1JNHtFS5NLvNsAQZf2UtAhzBIishy6z4hYOSHbfkhLiZKD1IoCzmvYfqAldFNJ8pHvMyWBDi@oIJNmTeB4GU99rIKQ40HczJeUuQMQMnIqpyABPHF6scDLnlnk4JQBPHwuabYpuc5FE26BFHC6KZhYUZcucWwlyx70XwwYdeLg6m4oWZH2K/x67my8mu0wCrzTKjv0PCgVxTdlWnZnSsG5pr0QDtptkL7jjuJjkb2MHGIxpLl3IYA9SjEoShnyPzroV@GL@CQDUACmchiQSHaqHfiRhRBO2o8raLQrMS6FKUYxwYR7PggUDpAz6z8EK1WH0FC6mKhv1PnqU2FSiI9IOcPHLLklnOaTEmF1TFCSoLgtYn@oe2rRAbvgeC65eh6PV/cKmxsk/00c7LDbL@x3cyuGFWZmUNLd/r@yLtqX3Td3iUoC2zwoTU2Jh@/ZWx9jeEGk9IjviO/uFHN06b7TTq1YrtAmzuCIzHoXIczmTHa@4sncKQZCzccVZZwKz58svhTliszXMpW@gEXciPqfmOjWXWqhUq/4TQrTiajDjPVYaaYUdDjUVGtgKTl0y6NYZOsIvMr7GVguogHu@LcqtthR65j9Ny0z@iOz/iaHu0jCxpQXx/E29MljDpcL@7TQX7S@4mGOOtFV19NpbTcIN5wMjBRNIZWnzZekIw/D0Yba5XZcCzhgwdoolwRumm8ANfSYNSyLQNkENETVQw0VyyXhdG9wZBvQUChn8U9OS7QAykYXAlCDXcwEYktHuU8KMtODGRNwb5Lzd4nZhCrBTx5jsfwexCNR@HkTURnAJq6HpVjhe4XphP2M7hPQq2gFTlbCsKCHRUYH/mG9jWcg/pHuyDgscNEVLIxZqqw6CXfhoVGBaSq1dI86MGHUX9A/bvG8RUUwTuGzge65YUpNX@EN44prIjEsAKksQbQcYP78i5BsYxXTVAXOLFAi9tYHoR3RAdFA8KGjnclgmzExR2E13YpzQN@iZUCnSCfuOJoiLRUDFVUNRAOz1RLD9JlRvMMFfCiLqcSC/0AoVjWBcF9CO7rw96C4B7CHvmLgj0IxqutFgRbEMxtTuaHuxDONakFEYY4iwbsej50z4e6ZSvcYBpNrW@4wFZYJhMQNmQBxiuG10cyPROm52yJ1w5ntgR7QfsktuIRkKUV0XjwPeIWCsXzOBTOF7E8OU3YNbszMzH5BCQ@p5xA7GL@6koCPoshAO0PRCmbDQ8y57UdFjTBPxp0O12sbSDWKvv06TbMBCMm@a/YDLiP1xDOc8ZKyKkVweE370T1yhN9FInmpxGm@XHpFuigUTmCRlmKRAhvW1G77ligL0JSFbWcyBuHlCp7HPk0/CYrh9IjoiNvFnfTsTTDPTjipBaZZa3IadyfqjryPaTUoUduRcIC92HplRly@mHsXDJ2DWKH1JziMyPBM6KVfm5h71eaFOBHjZpoU@GC1gDVsCYQnIOezus1LhM4sOV0mfvjPUFWEpi1ABjfr3gOAIY7gAP2bIEYD/pEy9G4zQ/I@UJpLUtT@DzKTUSmQFjdh07/AI0LCSe67BFenZAUSWwOaWaih@VGetWmm9xU8bikn1@4BjcaSz9OI45slp@I6x5DL1lmBRZujKmwm7vl0G9Hmeuo@hL6jq8slhVBpQeceB8WvFlA6DuZLFmEUpMlKI4okGS4o0uiTZ7zO6Vo6eI88AmmtXjbXqiBIVaVZDjizAEGAaAox1Nlhc5Vi0Sn2N16PgyUm2ykheGNRZwrQGWvSHFxjsO5feq8477h1hyiSDwELQVRw/QCzKxOoNuCGhyk04xzrGZOZKQntOmu67aVQGESCgNBCCygIVKWbxcK1SquXkbZQ3ZC6WVdYUUd9LsV8FkSXtSvgAcqn4I3EYmVLjWbCjabmH5j@XShFoVjbwRZBas7OBnEpQ8rT/tj7FAFejA3USDxcc8X7QwWcp564oR4kHd1Byfe6LQwGlrvyOgfVgTGqcFAO9o/THVwM2eWge@RFruHr@NDF6tiaagTh5UezDKplRCbnR0Zs4kO3/hNaik/8j261Nl0LkGpbk2kFDMdfp1CGa8lzW3hRCzeKiqkCc170yQPsAnUFOamOeaVIm4exV3asirxPX80KVSU8IQImpe3zcs2aP3cIn7g@mP6ncBgoaCNBkOXQkRGtDeQfbI@RfvVC7RKK0YMAp0dghPFUXD9hvtO@FxUrsgVpCKefqHGQDQwJQlc@UyWsf4QUTFf12hKvmbqRg@RQN77xIdTUF3EyTeSH1Q97mVDUuDiIDhtbsU7oLk5zIK0E39C71B8fC@ig/vQFCLyvRinSDThiiG26w6QyXGqDdPvAAE44R@cnD7bOz7WxGnIfEUAVxH4PDGaYNCGQHFrsJgmxdUA3I7JK@UBFhZh8/yqEXCSv0QjzFaQCZvCFZKT0wr3e/IS5Ir0NlOMML7KoxNJaDlZvPlIy4Kwmh6AHoW0i5IpsWS5IFkQOUaKB3dSQzcMNLR9afZdwHiXrq0uclo8iMiBTqRIkH8mzN9vYJ7NEHkenpsJzyXCNR7OkYpiaUbPiyKV45Hk1HUU74bJUbTsTF5VBoU@eEW7dzTXi@FduS2ur8EgzYoi18Kq5FwZBuwkAnKxkHdzap@HLCXShAwehjd4uODvkqj5EMtE3CfJ/PEpiQoyycZVmIRMcanmWDa/yToKIQnLcNsKT471TWzHG6WYEBHiJAdiAq/1xWZbq0ZQMsVA4lCbkWs7T2RNTEk9VqbRUPnlt9MNa04biVGJ8swQ4cbUk0A@FLwUA0EwkdFY0HJrQeKJSDyJgcVYS0G2UrATO9nAoWjTTbyK0@af8Cdo7Enkgnip@YEPOOZjXni@kpUkEAndJXk@mZLSZOiNTO4pCnVLLxLlPZmGOF9IvHJxBGr06PbmIE@Tr7d13JHTXgrlRFxQBJJihu5hiKB0FKEYsO@iKsTAG@k3@RXpC70PWqFtjlkddWqdzkySEouZeN@yj@eO4QmXzB8NBrYl9s2xK1ouEycKldZxsSeCGFMaNOkADXB4/Cy6xOIjJNLYIUK@QjuOKMDHG7jp5laGV8OBaO1YAHKoSXVnwi@VxW1mJb6kaLKRz@9gp6vmY0jwmuOtJ7yoV5OChVte1A5v384QVCAouOvxG8jdTlmSfjSyjIvdL1ipUNgsFlaLMZIFU9UFbXUtfoF4GFAqFAuF9eKaJO26gwk3HVEMFWGt5RBglr3Ajv4N8KZ5iVe3SXXoMSgiHovpm96l2dYk6dhs0xxwa0QUQVbGu9zplAraR48@oFvheUJ4u7Gf5VcYA4fhE/tnfjaAQYbLWQnXaAem17eGfCXXveSX2Afr0h3Xtt0rmojGJWFOD0zUN4dAlBWVJVGiff8CF9JdaDs@UEMXN8zqLfeSzukQZAA91cLjjWiBVcJNqgghnhm/njKGCeRn2LrVR3aagwDuYokoECAARWuPDPNWHCRC4jNxCK7ObbvGCE8@0IOayYP0c6mtQHM3PQukb0RgqhVKFsMdKvj0@cEJOzncP31bP95j4D46Pnxz8GzvGXv6DTt9vsd2D4@@oSNg2fPDFyBdTlj91TPwfXV6fPD09ekheMj1E0gpU4BUf/UN2/v66Hjv5IQdHrODl0cvDgAagD@uvzo92DvJsoNXuy9eQ2f9RZYBBPbq8JS9OHh5cArRTg@zlGuQTIrSscN99nLvePc5vNafHrw4OP2Gctw/OH2Fme1DbnV2VD8@Pdh9/aJ@zI5eHx8dnuwxLJj07OBk90X94OXeMw3yhzzZ3pu9V6fs5Hn9xYupgh6@fbV3jMgnSvl0D7CsP32xRzlROZ8dHO/tnmKBItcuEA8QfJFlJ0d7uwfo2Pt6D4pTP/4mK4Ce7P3oNUSCQPas/rL@BRROUu6gCtTL7uvjvZeINFDi5PXTk9OD09ene@yLw8NnROuTveM3B7t7JxUmvTg8IYK9PtnLMrzghbIGGEAtCAf309cnB0S3g1en0Ge8Pjo9OHylQiW/BcIAlnVI@owIfPiKlxaIdHj8DUJFOlAFZNnb53vgf4w0JWrVkQonQLXd03g0yBCIeBovJnu198WLgy/2Xu3uYfAhgnl7cLKnQoUdnGAEgIn5vq1Dpq@p1FhPgBd3ArNKAedmqTrZwT6rP3tzgJiL2MABJweCW4hsu88FzaEt56W5S263LuDNrvKJqZDbD@HZPXy2BxofP5dPjvxfQ6ezlVy8S4RBRxMGwqtYBaW@6rxttkbdc7xWHofmYTK@gt33u1k83VLFC3nOpNvukOML5ZQglTo/f1M/h3Huyfm5mr1PygQad6UQu9xvi6WKMtqu3qZhfmJuKU6o2iNxlk6WH2wRn2t5FE4@qCyfb5siGRqHIOBgmkgc@gTA2igZyWpEd1gsS1piTs4V0Ylk05NFwfKm68OP8yl64X1DzAOEM7dbyOdxDEto4MlyLMQfMqFD18TJa2QHYHUoS803zYuuUohnh0N@MUGlBmko7hCGgV1FvSN5y@xOJc9Npydk0ZaHlJXguJ3gGBx@py@@CZIxUS@aRyVT@NQePdQAG8oIlEKVZ0WGQsL6RHnEk@P@bT5XqFbCo1rouLWX9a8P3uJgrlBaq0z5Pw/9edtCqz48OxD6uwala9LjeZNHgAZm4fALSGJN@JJqPh9LA1oZ6ZNhZDwLqIeRrqw29KnYVfdM6tbxBCJ@HEM8PXTGnjWOYw9i@Ivj@sunr/f3QXIitmtb65sbFUmcaOQNv87y5zeYD56XS9QFLfrKAjWNgmKtZBf0nv2Zwwhjpydi7WFEPKg8qDTyxDuNw53JXEfg55fxaSAsro8nODl4iJmMhzB5Mr@1e0kK@HVuyxQMoCSKqmJp@vqYNHwdVCXiAYPvQrYnVGtj/EHYYfMPmnhYIMFAgsXM/mA4Ac6FwQXJPXk/MOiksQ2ZbWEUTQ74eKAHNkicMCgzycoVbRzpTfB2rBZBr8WKxvZK1U4pAYmlaSyCQ/DoSEvI4sj1gxbMPS3w@VrwGzi/EYcvYhAepVUfngAZ98OUueBwRD7nLBqGgNysVaGKHj0Kc9phOJGqCqT4/H/yaL54ayBUuEEDmwIcWB6FdA5DaBL6SVpl15xT8dQUhFMRHCvegXPnFUdAqQRHzoj34IQ@xmFFB/aR11WYhxRE@SaIEpIzQabfiR4E/78hTebA34EBJ0CPqEVy2HJG5j0pSVA5rWD0SkSxrgKLsZiZWkTNuNc3EZibeMX0woIJM7wxX1gCEojamQQe3/AjW5U5BEAmx3mNePvFAxKoEfd0GDk9obb7gK/0e47RHyjBgadBVzEDt5klnSsbmMjhi8qX8Asslt0LPL/uCe2jJZmBAy6QYq0Je@jLHEamSDIHC51foUmPsJUTayIZikELj9ipIJpW0PjHwsIo6mXaQegNqKKLD1MNl0PwzMaEwA9WQAIBQrZP8QILskGeNUR0brnRkp5m@ZnoxfEUchCB1C@zUzJ/9vUOjZmxKxK2ymgUjVkinIdtcSZmyxxeYXdhc@hkox1BY8pDMhPHTMRcZKhGBMJX1YDq1MlehdjTNCXya4j9a@fCwTs6TD7FFcTQEidsxre4a@ylTodt2vcrtxxlnkGy1pL5Hzhkt27w9UqcmqORO@SCI/2HfkQR0DivULuEfiiikm5coKcc8Kh1lbPG8KC8cqLkwZmRMGagE4HnKf03CwcEyCtTNrBMPnPCSaQy78iqDwP1BV287Yaub9Al5pmrUChADnzQYFaoQYgy6k1opDnb2gi/xLYFND4tg@Z0daW19FFfdzp637InZHX6we05ed8Z@QO8rV6W5eRsIB60gibogPvQZG8tp@1e@ewpNAecSDp59frkKDnxF5v52uUzX4x9CXmwp5SzNAO@g3tSfLczhKoxK2wibnDyoukemicUMy00rTVBD9z44xEDQb79UDP@4tVr9oXpmB7og0dkc8leWIbpgPgAZYqsMP0elzQYfR9zPxG5s33UXWhmp8JMiyZ1wrk9SWQgoGWRtRRoioCwJ46txrn5CbB6bE5Qmy1wVK52MKnUcwditwVOmqKyyac4OyM7K@HZ2G8PTp/jYJwPzGluBrq1YK4P5xK56tTnk7VQGE93hhMgijQ9eQNo3zV3ozHabAEQpcXkpEFdH6/2aeO0n@1DUfH6LSEFqAeBpmpal3gYL03D3aeOyM5WTJtFdKuI/atZfjxwIDoStSdFtZfFM9m1LFvfZqcm8i47snUDRljsZITJV1dBD3zq@kOM@rLOWKFULBZzxVWcon19UteoIeA3OKFVkg5eHh0enwIhxRFEAWOEfSYSnw5F5dZYQI4cHo0KpX@PAjmIDxKz9J6Ihyp4cE6CXOErFnJZhro3dJzuhRL6SXWYpmRxSt716GBW3G0DLJRojpCrf4XCly@NUE4x6Fk6GlYc7sq7lhBP2i1JCd4jbjbwlY3roe8pMfmBADDH5AepPBoZtMWxQlAnfbMfYm8Ng95d5xGk6TNlQ4LxuVRgjnQ2jVoSUE@Nw2mbaCPh4@lMff/S8EC26JfAcmjCEmw5Ap4h2aSGpdFblm1BGwC8jJ6LHQ4XV0FF0BRE/MRZiWo8PMsQOyTCZc5pUNC62m4/jMqxkqRws53wH/gTw2WpLgyzcaTlD0yzTSdRjQb8qCUM16CV29Bz8G145egMJilVILtJD4QNHnkHsm9k49583EvZ4nUuBaUBrgq2b572cFjPAUGJTobUSPFEXGXOCDvLcJ1XpWrXgSEwrYqEWLCREkAMsrgoBVhBfRNDkIvYJYvbfWyq7@l9lpiQDnv0B8kAhMVXdc1kQAAeyy6cMxE4k1ZDBKa2cAbI8H1I3J2YA0u@YHnR7hQ3pSm8jFC4iRoSc9/CI8r53IDLui7@YmQtoBhfIzRpjXBmYyjetVkEeNMxi7MxIVZ4QFssZmkOzNxcmKvzYeYETLFYeeBc0oY4TEVswUvBT9twQT4iIaLif@EGope27dkuX2AKS9@13RaeiwmSAnLDxyQbVWzcm0ZgCULHQ/kmzeR5njtBkQTqYm9ToLuwHWgfZo3tBDMWtTOHV5QIqPK2RHvCGPVd1JzIiT@iRZFTThwOilrH1OmgiB73BdmNYGUBUvjIZRa1TLTEiccXOSeT9BNJilNJBHLJJK1EkpIU7QSfql1MgaIfn8mSBXoJWSVRDbBqWEEFqa@P@eimQBv8aJoGj@RO7DgsNQWDYMSGwcI9gxi9KUVHYCSW7XkewSuZ4JHFt7ws05GiheR5UuPAdI/EAMVKhE/omBVHEQVSBRnoJTxeQw2QEeXaoSROTFKFBeYBUqLYHu7VUuK5qGWWGuh81RBj@dixxbNuEA1wlV6GvxWmiAxycWR5JDy2QIhCIDwdbdGAoSyvlkAOFqSoZ6a3mICDGpS4/CaTMd4NKEqiXQWSO4TJnTOyG0ChPwdHOUl8f7UPeh33xR4lJhpOUOHDY@KFkmeOYXhGa8wEgvqfcMZaePIzI0LpIZBvRDk3g14jWYqFsae7knlxYr1KSIXbIgfEDum0MPLi3oZIh3MIKO949BjpXuAksSBd0AWnfU4y0lKsIW0mdw2LS6gk2WJCl6fNzhHAySoPkMtOlUqKHRUjSjjdjUiJnjPBJErsDa/BYQ/5QcEckColUiH9F1U4mjvGG/bCeEUeT1T7Io4IYQX1fhtbhJGDer@NLXjkWLXfzhbBWdEhaSn9NF8kaoKTAI0SxYiB5pTiMigIGMdjjadiEUKTZvysGNNW5mAbk6pirlOaUZVCEomj4ZJ50GPMK0bcPpZkRyBeI6yNZlRa6OOMC7MdnnghSh8OkWpyskvgtTl90BMWOsiB6qip4pUkYQKQ2HwSTIyZ@9x2k04MSvMBC41B8VTUbi@5uzcBNuhVCuqsQhmcjhQhvzMX@dzsKVXREKs8e/9OaF0msEaDJ9drY2xZmrPiK92BVSaGVbJ0sRpKkngBpNy9IOXuASkfgyQa9ir0l@RMeXgOsHkXiLOzWRj0eAcDKQEDJG3bwklsHAdf6ZO7YC6BspUimzqdW5WFCSI9@S4Yj6dh0LnrvXA1Tnj2dJx1@2h67vSpZwspm@SVORiFWKVm0coiWiS1abwr4gWqEo1ttYtWzwpHAqm7a5qfEyESoylxL1wESiVPLQqBRe2/uIB@2Vi1JtsDRzwxDQPasvSZzUFDQvAZJr5VLEwQE2TJcagISBLi9tBp4Uej1enTJfBA@YXJ1DtL8oRP@MQmnYpQNC6xEhwXDOEi4RT0VoF8mzc8uzP/1Nz8B@4AdJzOXAQofh/n8fmk1JRIj1TTqaH1vfqyuf3ZbLnietvU2W/3b@SPZopegqLjxnRo1I55JXr/2yCLsgQ18Fto8o2ARxYg@XAukrjQrovJLeaM@i3Tk@7T1HkKDR98jLSYcyUplWJ1A4bM4uQhugGKjkc2RZaoBiMj@Gw0wPUanxt3YuPGOTKTM/B0XLw8nmJrMmZBc7R9U3fEUUSiw@x6uH4Rxs3i8ei4uYtysBwDCO2bsenP9/zOj7YpQtAi@RayVubXPXI1XW7PschGOQm0uK6pTJJjWu67QMEJtRqKVZ5WVALewcXQFa6ZC30JFHN1/hTYfbSn2xQiYOJFWYoB7xTo23m0vJiYo0FIyrBq7kHKeepWOMt9D3Vrcl91678BJacrVIq5hfYgOtjynUJtepBPF94GB1/35xzd8uZ0fz9x4ElrEowK@qa3XigU8BCcmdvtcIECV4ktN5@Mncc58fzg6kvvTSuPSZP32c29zg5xgKgYG5cmkE9waWIE/U3sOC2cz3FwV84Hn8fkJ/C0GZlxWqFx@5tTYj4CicQzy@w9FhDL954F102D4siHDAJKYG8GqVENvZQDMzkgD3p08ESd0CSNgNG4WexawIWPau1aeiCueKR5PryOR72OtiHKz03bdrPsrevZ7SWZ7w5NJtjfjyco8ChoSsgbj0/XQ2SZeWnZsSsyMAri5tqmZrtdfscS3p/LZz9pL5NnDnAlTcF@7Njs7o0Hitx4JwNjQpEzWMwMk5u4vacrQxcl0xL63WD5gWSA9r1i9/WBYhCdpiNDHyj2UkUuwGgVL9Hk1sE4n7ILRUZjDiURReXnwnCa3R0biTofXe2DazkKFB2DJdwuR1u/qXqpJAuih8SVz8bFDtKwwGEInPAIxPuluKngoVO//Qdnt3HmADc30hxvuCU2dt5YvBzBZDy2LHY57HSgefGZ@Fpw1FgAjkRlrkhWCkgaUbGe@e0I9Bkl3fHT/AA7NLU5mThGApFGqZll6dGws5UGCL9TGaWgBYrmB/REs4mvctCs90d0T0okz2gaDg0oZuUOJjjHBJL00Kh@e6XU63W2PMhkWL3@FBy5HKs/rbNn6PH0KXsG70/x/VG1tL5e4ZZzz9Rr8HwaeN6wpwCDuiC8k@0ZvEIYXbWEQyms4uV8dTlbWT6v7tQqfr5Rf9rM57vg@rvf/8nf/dM/ydfFy/f48pReGu/CSJqm5ZeN6@VHNxV8bzxrppdbjeVBM92tIJehuH/t@bqtx7aJacY/yL24wc55Q2Wg0arVapqlP33irrNh5PQiJ15iECXX7UFPp@SMINSq6Xr60SNw7VTTP06reHKH8NdD/4/gz1SU5bReTKSl5eP6ye7BQfyeoPD@0Q5qmrjgrgvjNMvxLSjU@1Swep5rME1jzRx7H6KHBt3nPGISRZZGi1GOzHcCyaB0ZH1PVqqUMTc/JQMjbvfErdH6fpfMiwIDJQojYzBM9LBd5qZzBCMDAg/jV/imVIU3Nyw@oIu2btVco7ix3sylUinKmaxzzw0Sc5TbILqq2IgZy5KlGz9RbwBNBsqO0BDlBgOASIxU6qEBeDwyxDkODt0NiQWm8wrTqXTsaAwGKJn8VsEH4VW8jLQNsbMMe1jCDjrzEW23Rt1gcl/DPUAgvAGdXTO6nVfml85OYpcBxi4CxhNPpm@JD0/Zje6Jp2viA4DG1EkM0wA58WB0TxxUFWUM3kHdmGWq9@K2HrYWrCyJHfeuPenaeHkmbZrwr0A6AeVVUVm2E5yKiDnwlC2zgwufvEXzCos27ZFiaOJeWMfA1QVQCxwbD9HlCl9wbTJokNAeUMMR53B0cM@3Yjt8q4DbAaeKV9wH10MTG2bocCfOULioRkfE8PSBHFgZgO464DGRqvAemdkSe6CRtzDQeDBrcDlQRUpa0BOcNmigRV@xGRzmr4qWJFNbCU12QKvs4xAUJ0WAKBhToxNnQTRM2HvbeT/v2miyUqQseTYlbokMEivMxhILr5Qd3/Qrq7w0eD6tow8FeQeu71vCUEVUE1nh8F3CHkA9S0s8M8Et8Yu1VwZhi4qXL2Alcwx8jvNg/MwRyB0KKbggERGNN9HykNvFpRL2uHS7Oorcljm0DL5Viue@FMjiAR0Hgr783JSFGcHggZuDBhVMOZwxsQtVWIJSVUdwiE64Kxnbfy9UvXWiWWBixPENTm0ZNELmCGvnLCJSBDHkBAKQJIrAkSanBAUfJBjTNrvWMJEmyzddi/2lvBQ3Aemxkb8ni8cYdacoi7ZBwc3WoUh4L@gdGGGj4A3CQNBucevq@bwXFAZ7NW6LFabkRaKDM7Zm@SOURwE6cayhBQP5sPlmkzVEnSv2dZbP@ZjXScSqLKqFW3Mg4AJFLi9WaCc/ARDSYpomuQbe7ztFDRCnU83g/2vvWnrbNoLw2fwVNIVaEitHUlI0SNMGcG45tAXS3uRCoiXKFSCLgpZqYgT6753nPqitJRtu6hQ52KBI7mt2d@ab4e63TgsPguy9AYyD27fkpKMa4uXuYkiwp7x1vGhNd5Hz6v/NcoOuvNog1SxMPngLxwHYaLeY/AreWE0durFZRmfgh1KBOqrfBe1f2myXgPx5kbpYFP9IeFeorUejKG269PA5IaW1EpaN2n5fNpJqe13qP8LU523mbvikDA4dD@msu0LsIE9P2JiDNdV8mZqhM9CfO@WQEAoGuzJde0dETua1mKN4cK07anPXObvY0FAfXrW8tlmQBS6N8TOnvIh7SN7z1/tHhLSjEM7Ftq7e1Y@P6Sl2R7VZzO1NOnYecEEBMFggQtHtyxVcjugI60dyC1APLEAR8E6VwpRwnSSMPMTDzH4212@rj51B7zK7zHrD7191M/KTLQ5rTQ14Rq1piSuqN@gllOJ7giWWFXJ/lazCN1eL2QwQhxyeAEmlNPtoLNmOMEL@yao7c06mNiMlXmaeLjfn0Il0Q2RN1@tNcX1T0OUv1e@b4vYdGCH6@euK@/M3zO89GCM8RJWevOc5ejEDqJHt0E92Y@KoJlLIvADkM60JGtQlUyVYuBARQLknAC7Ttt@EjfXE4LefYxcWPZPdhE6dMEIxvDZ8wpyAE3IBcHsC@GljvgdjU1wYQ3x2fEmP2CFoAkh8oDt5vLucgqH@Mn2DaQJKP8eoRgOvQ6Vxql66hAE6UJfr7qZUvPNxYmtvJuLY1NM/xzfbZb2Qlu01S9uFiXopi2KLJ4xIM5FFENnwFj/hBqgf6SHRKytGx5BhU3ZeOzDf0QJmqfNlSFE5KYgTprl4/qOKm9pPYUcHGsRVYQb359/R@BjsXt/RN4zu36irgQTrSOLmdQe1F2XuuRvMOGjtbGpbfRo4H1gPEApWI1@jTmbVvPP7GHsYKeBJmdjO/Rw@@5fs5PIdFNnYSUn9UllGzTrM@fq0f7iXDs7pa4Hv1cJIocSmutHVluJOeM6rd8wzzCDcQf5fO6wHPLcA/Xmi0v2ZPnY5DSZaAA51Y5wnTgtiyDL7vUBt9cGIjyRI5ayFAY3lnHmklWjrI2qDnRJ4k@vcBNmKmGxLI@oNstgznj0LI/YedRW9WQREr8KYmqlSFevmDJt8DMaonrNgWtcQU/qQPXUG1GHWiBNuh8FBQZX7gho@TFBcr5ic@MmjiSkUQCilXZLEhq9VHbJh1J/rlitgTy@R4E4tEG7kEQG69F3Tq1gzO@hARfavFAzn6cU1qMUQC/OqgcLdY6@HHUjT4IaygTjeUrPdlD8AIgZ0lcAfQF7UUrQ/LoiAAGTtJ/YlYoJAaZC8bTRCuMnSfqubyJfZPi8l6gxfDrtUyBElJcG5GfeG96wG8VPMfI/mAg0KQY48HQtVyGHrR7buH8LSQfuiIWnQyC4ozeo5X69xy@6hKHW/pUdkpZB92k0fGKCmWMlztkEY5@m3khOoAiMNXLAFhVHqbyXAa0poxlq3zHA41xF/sH@oge6nFP9WGRui5LcjwAKEgaIDxGeYq3SwIARaSkgTtP2NaYOo7Yb5aCkOqhFcJNEGI1kt@FBMdTQgZHuFrLTRmCJBbS@qGI2aaoQobUWTpR3e31ss6dNROcVAuI1Sma4XD5awQ7@tbNFYLaZEsVkG6spvztlZKnWjkHUDY0Qd/UBQXI9AGJcrVs7NoQtKCG@S4MWkwDSxqG8djT/wC/KGm51ncSCC6tXhEBeh6Tu5b1dW8nHpUNK75IMNuq4aVAIkEz6ATkkeXW2S@wq0Kc8Dg5QCel/OKL1XTxw7VC1Renwssi1@OWRb7NueW9PHaANaH@bjZ0YfopBx9ifNfZqlE7a/FKaAfzxA8dyuorZ0YaDtTc0rR7tukYepn5mazNdr9/kR/Ti2ScVsBuZ4i7vxb2vIAjfi0@lznpw5kSGX4n4GU510Ll5UIbiYWJWmZyapnV@WkmPmub/KP0aSmgth0wlkR8uLiLMFP11VU2YAw0WAGBygdaXk1w7ZLUKHiBOO8KcQqZzMmY98LjOZW5DmYylW2iD1oUYwxnq7KeqjIJb7JMe729MVssHiWQONcWieJXho5n0h2TG4LD8al7VyimnnDp7lrTVgixcPzOPz4jQXoIV8MlvzDCcqBfDJ5QARQwctb3t@MF@0lv/J7eGw7yt8eaqGIX/y8CW34p@GICZ3IGYaBTHuBUk1xcAbpbPvk3qAabsiDzkX2MPlVWF5MG@0vCpanimRYTh170niiorF25Fi6w@VpLADVQqk@GO0INS1PKcnmcztSdrZn9Dc384Mv/hqhv/PZvhv)

Zephyr block comments are `#- -#`, they don't nest. Block comment starts on line 16: `#--++`. `-++` fixes brainfuck and derivatives. Inserted a space
to break `-#` in Ursala (line 32). Main code is on line 224: `-#print 175#s`.

Inserting two lines at 16,17 meant that Klein 201/100 should be moved to bash line. I tried this some time ago and failed. So I moved `/` on the first line
instead. Two spaces are split with `"` for Trigger.

Moved first `exit` on line 19 to remove `e` from CSL path. Klein 201 refactored by analogy with Klein 100. Having `<>` for CSL on Kleins line became problematic, so it's been moved to a separate line.
Commercial doesn't allow any additional code inside it, so it moved down.

Zephyr prints space after the number, it cannot be avoided.

Interpreter is written in Python 3 and does not have an option to specify file encoding, it uses OS encoding
to open a file. By default this encoding is UTF-8 on Linux and not UTF-8 on Windows, so Zephyr interpreter does not work with polyglot on Windows.
The encoding that Python 3 uses by default for opening files can be obtained by this [code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEnPzkxJ9W6oCgzr0QDwtFLTy0pKEpNSy0qSk1JzUvOT8nMS9fQ1Pz/HwA):

```
import locale
print( locale.getpreferredencoding() )
```

Answer (score 5):

## 192. SQLite, 9428 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bcyPNkhj2TMj/wC81DX4DgLg2QIAAQWAGvA05wyE5vAxnPpIfpgE0gCYb3T3dDRIYDr84sh1rrVYP0mqtWGktnbMrO7wPivCGww9WaCMcYb0qNvQbvn1ybDji/IPjzKzqCy7kzHznHFmOEEig65KVVZWVlZWVdemW4vR/85softihqY97uukyV3Vc1rG1G9XOsPUxe65oTjFfiEQQqmH3hgPVcJ3VSJTJjGlGW@uAn7nmtWpon1QbwvOMWbbZs5UBc/uKy1SnrViqw8yhaw1dZnbnJyswtjUwr7Q0phxoRg/AXNW2bNWl@GXGTg1dGbQ6ylRMcSpDy4Z4h22q@ufBZ5e1zcFAMToOQJYYe23ajorwbdVxTEy@wthoS21PIS0DqGJr5l5j/8VUVIWxF1BExdLVEVNajmsrbVczDaRJjh3vnx4fTqWQZfb2ZHt7OjTPXqVNg20P29fTUQV2ajuKrkzjX2aNoWvuutPhRdboqYbC8plKJj8dWWLrtjKTZIXZqtLparqagQZhadZXdUu1GYawrmmzXSiSXs6Vc81GkDLTxrTlIHIabYXphYI7VZ98Dghv2n3VgBLmpiNlP3IqIu9HdDTKQLHHLO70TRv4yGZDR@2wW9PuAHMZ@jiRgvRs9Im1FEctLSOCgo/g2jBvDWAi14SmbY1dlRmmkabECLjM5L3mNGPlixjaONidDi@x/N502AowWvu6O9uW@TI7Mq3xdGiFvdb25rFzIcc7wobZgdaYipPZoQJBlE2Y8NQ9D22zM2xj13H7KqTE7oat6UTa0Px1ZolOnkEHi1L7czBAfWwO1HBuDjNUIK9jqW2tq7U5W6gjVzUcyNDJMA2KcKvpOuuoOiQIsLdTzDGxcYKglq70M@1MBNkKc2GDa51prG1ZjEcxXYMibefKTMW6s08Qr/cdNrIGzNEGEO22zW5XVdkn1epD8kjHjDD4tK2pavm@RRVgDNUjjWpBd0bSmNj7gU4ehW5txQK@dwQNXG0AwkpzYw5TFUdDcQhJHNXoEFUtX1CaTJlgWHajQXeFqg9twu2oNnUYwgudy1YBpeKLqvitrbku8TxrsENVsdmJraqJSaE5kSVkZmIOLlYkQ426thbbOtiOQePyFBnFgsa0CydvXkYUlqmxxWYVvjVJqka29jfZ3eIFurmMBAaw7LiSYLUfmZO9uFDhO5Jb2Z59HwGsEaCKzrKm5WaVtAUFTLtQwKyCTnSlb/IZSw9lzNam2iLEchyqA60BooO9TVHN2kPbxnEgIKpyDZXWTaMH9ITK2kMD6WGwUg6aoG2CGE8x9QaoBnKT2gh6NVL4pK9BoznYJKFuwUczIiiMZ8DGgqJevo6pDwkOUjou8jJQBZIixt0ue8u6iqZjEohHVLzUtuoMdRfTDI0OtjyMVmonw7xitKHjAtDAvIHsFEBKAcD6g1C/pEIBMDSESVXFqJ/@8Z91ej3A02i3QTIJdn3LOmabxl2FCguDGUOGBXGoU7EALoW58@SQwY2iax3FxeyNsciCCkG53ppDvcNMyNC@1aCX9pUb6NnQudquypmcD9UpNlCuuTTROOdCxQdKCxqWMqC8qdpp9nwDWqmtRqLEM@nB0O2WWdraYjEn@0P82Wr82ZMLFQqXyCSWFrPZXhUYLrNEQeCLPcY5bxsTA4zjKo6pdSLW2O2bRp6l20xq10xLNeKxCRyxVMxuxRIZlHLxRFWrtTNdzejEY2vAi3XIOJaotmvtc231sjqVPJwloLlFNNhd1Xg7IUVA5FCnuMkOQBZnQLS/TQtXKM50mkhyjM6EgpEw02E3PCBKqgrypYkMAnIo4@iqasVzGTmBYgLh5tYbI@bVdAqHqPCqdpmMRWPJcNUJA9R0oqLYWU80E8WWbvVxyAGiGI4FI4GNvNuGcRYlo6O5oC@mWIv4mkYRkCwkE2/VmK3igOzzEXVJ3uUwfRoFpcAQdKHJnqx2Qh0ZhAD0ZdeZkca6eQsZUplwmAHRYWCmSg@aBhLzijR4RXhOFDJZJa4mALaWysrplgadALsbyHTB86G6AXghz2EAG@8kIdkzUMaApc2H1aDDMK0LfWkA4gF0mbaKMgeEj8oHFMxkSP3PAQ0ZdeVcOl8sTvaxmS7m2tlG@nsQ0p@yj/YkrHxjQmmAkaer3jJdMXpDpadyPYop7bZquUJQQU0cF0TR9HhDgWkxeGacfmTx@XTeNIh4qkWQBwp53npiKFRQugg1Pa2DMGWKmGiA3meDWNLH07kDwM1U5tIHBJkowAfpgSJ4GgAwmTpS20MXpBow8G1fa/eBZ7F0BpeLfBCazh6CwrmDZE93/ayxMHL9aT6SyfpBWIwHUaSxRWfxwOCKqOoTAdT44YDHMSvOYA5i0y8iDASh0ExWyQDvfQHnwDTMOUiBkD5aBJmM4e0AmtgxKpQwcHlqF3VWX8v0mwjaDNX4DvJf33UtZxXGCc3tD1sZ4JTsiT3edQ8MZJasa4811@Tulm62QCw70D@zXg7Z9rCljaYqRGF@G145kRtQwLoOq8HI/XEIXBePdR0QmBS@gcChKIkEN6HgvxIAElAGCBXvOiSKt0GoHI@NdlzKUFfKQKeTUkzCjivBZEXCVD5dNswBSiF2RooBanowadMM1PSFzCeRr8wd6nzZT3pdLJa5MjUjfhd78uRJbDVWB8n@5MkzcK2h6xm6kuB6Rq40uRAugy5KkSIXxp5TCgy7jN2fe5hHiUtsthGOSp80K66cr64WLlPKuSyeeXwmQNSBZAPoND4ATyxRq6EzkZDqt1DRTKs7WfsNlM7HbVuzBBFeKjcK9wsqFIgM2sDCSaCtVnGQfZwmg5oNoyAore1@3I5dnOcuLi/uLjrJi/tYClMnqkqtBZWC/OKDTM82hzBcJs6XV9PyZSJxXoBBslWL5WJL8Xg5rUNGSiLxXTmRVDi14zEVpHb84iIGRBX0OW/3bcI3SuUTCZ9UUA4cmEEnjMcyd2XIv5W4TCRjkDYRS8EUoxaLAWXaSASHKo2cOUGgg6NXnDAbyWSE2NC0r/E7I/YhLAMTLJ58G/h343hy0jq4BunK2o6Oqkja5toIeLNLPLBDD1/jWmW7pLEaMNxCDWC07fgzI5xLG0PSn0m5NcMZ0XQQISgMxx6Uq9oEDCLuaiOYIEC/H3uKEI7fqAttwITT1NXMGakmEoOOw7C7Z@ZqQ4d8WMm0nYAHQO8Bp6UrbejYk@guJHYBCIHPs9n5MYnqDOJpVYlmNV@qIwwsbcVA@nU00tqHmtNH8oJmhVMJuwtURZUddAOVqLbL2jDm94DS6khzuQ4PfHSMSXYUJ55ArbHBtS5U9lBjwEJ5NgAazs02zHdU0Bwwlk8e2ZZxo9mmgUTObAFqYPgqtsEU8nnkBTZqNHbzmw/Tdx5yoNhMsByibRjrNHHbTptlDVM3eyZbAgBkzUyGM/au0YYigM7nwvSSOdonIlCjZxrjKR5Ucbh3UEeUSwVf@1YQMkvwmSuQNWx@pQOAB@p8vPv9FowQcjGXg/J7vhx9/EqGsEzXEQPbLAAQBlcd@QZb8nvV6o8nzEHIH3wWCfxkqrxj8nm9AgMqlEr08E@UNNzJeQj0cy@q47nm1X2LNCQ0ZYRnGRO1B2UQ@qmoDu82UMPoVDCGeqSYQDrT4EH7boPsPOkP1Yja7ptMugANI19n2Y56k0WBI4Gg64OqnIasVJuUMT@ZMABHXHMIWl1H1bWB5u6SuUs3UHUJhmUvFm1uAYJDTXUjYr4RiFc0SQWy1uhx@K0RDkhORKUn2z/Y3GoeNk52alJ26NhZXWsBB3fU5gAUT111JDb9ibIjFZCJ9J@u9SPTdGu8ua519sVPFNN4yfc2m3u760eNo/e8EITG0QZDXcGirC5OAWDyY4r2elXIDti1zYGvkTuiIRYLSHp1wmKP01MRu4yxQ2GvD4WXMHyANvhMO9Jrt1na5F4/UACuICDa5WkM6yWTCEl2ej9QQJYJJdrqM3bLC6xgoG@ln7BfB@jmxT@cSGC@k3P3iNwxho4VqtmdLFP4jdvt4qjtB@cp@DqNrK4HwQUK5lb@Sfu6IMtM1FxgH98y4eOrA3PxzUTNBfbxFTk@XFWYj24qZh6oj6xEyHAVYi6uqYg5gD6mFcIUXrkI4soU99CyhchrbvSDiXzcFcKNSxsBKlroEEEeYJ5zx4AvOzhNtJEGPJKXJ2Ixii9WsHQHJidrCIL88hmXMSAItDjH6mTckRugKIRRpEHn4IsYfjxnBFlvKk3olUFpvZBQFEvrIMDkUpC46Cc2p5KaWhDsg/N2zetNEAHDUJf2QsJRfiLehN5qSbhT5HkL2qY1DvXluzwn/kAT4iTUuwqc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vxYSUaS7gTmBI3TNBEdrTHFqTDEu8iK@wX0Qkb9YxoV5LQUw@sP6x9M18s6UURkSyGMTltYmT3cDVzGXkImLxUQyu9dmUXdAZ6WcCdKZQszF8DBi0uvQzB2BVWMRguMMlHqTKS7Tqo9HOBA1evSUwmtsTMqCWZijZI3rgLH9eeSbtFROFaandISi3WZh8ofsLYOlKmSC7rZb2ECjQBYvuPeeA2cPWPLJBL@zPmLTYBOHdoe3qakc8/8MvOtAAs83TV8ak0PuOJtCNeKP7YGuJpOihn/ktSzBXQ11TiAzk@hLKtoKrCIruO@ajRs2EpdN9xR6g3iwaF5gTf6DXPMJnvOS2qg87qvecnwmReNJwxlMb2oBqBE@c@NE094HkU2Y/np6mTrqpdAgLn@BoatDavF3UEVf1Qxo0yJivKKdnnWPBcpjbH7pD/osrYF9qV83C73yqrE4yWa6otGQ1azpKS1Mf4QNbuR52zLR13aNKY9FKD3E770RoTEp3deWaO5vonE8AXkVb6/VU23s@BHbbB52dJhvZW3o8wiqexsRIB1Yew2nr/PchEG8Hie94mE6aTj/fwpDEIm3oNUhaXOZOh8ikTRFWV1pjnHT1v52zMENSRUHw1NrJZK6AY6e/phEsqFvWw@lxwKX0lcr81HyBnZNk3lQkyxfW09zgRHUWS@1f6PUwcmkDRU/nOyHng0LcM2YGrjmgNANPt3XFAWZyRXOoN9B89PMYg@Ng1Ea2ClyPsHdQHG9p66FVkiCNBRqGrjkW73HC85A0nbYvB2hwpwP9BEnRN0vfDim5Tj/tu@YLBLPt4krFA/z2FQKOLxLgMkyIgTLmQ7Rrm7f4fVDF6Js3Kv@dP@h9mluqrxBVaZ04Q2vPSd5pf4ldca2bfuZT8Xpuqdy2PjdcWOQn1fyvZWhH000H5tv4@xghQHN2HP47n5XDNNMUI02G47B7fjJRKItlhKHsgZZU9J6pl8q9rAI/Dzb30O6i@BfPrxV7vtiS5S@LLU87Mg1ZPB@U99dZ@/pLnEDWZRtXoULORwbbebJLrF48XEGYQ@DS8vzKbefKlDKT5caPhxrAbvdvlbH3/BlDykPU9YYUa0y6NSh/mKBSBodrc3375@S2/Hhuna8TSDNoV75UiVDjXusqiGf6nWlSls/J35hCzuW@Xjx19aE6VOdqeQetKxW3BnIzLe5IUHSdL2@e7B58Y6FyohqLwkyYBeKhkdCH@iRmjl9Vahy80feogFF0DTr5F1WcufLOAoXcwsn2ITgO0TGbsGcMrYnGDdHuaGgcPU65vuX1bLMzUUiM@VaJVP6yIjWhszsqfR/S77cGJsyPzQEoDMZXtL9AShYN/juBmEICNWPC8DE3e3@pGhRaUDygRbVrJ402768TOvmHJvUEXKnAtM1Q3TH@PkTpeUK0ZZr6t7QMyNKORluA9TRuG/1SC80oOWLXAgvMFw6aQlrdhwwXfJwRM0ygHs6m3Ufmz2Ez0yNTwhmT@SOjVciA/qVJJozUZBly7Lbnfoghj7BTy5lyZuVRduQ6qNlSdYU/RqXlx/BVMoVH8flah1BuacEFF2n4skywrhWdEj3WGIildWCC0lcHKnkf0eyVztXQ8R4PAo1M/M6JzmRpkeGBdJYGfd3A34kloJA25JoGTKlcxe6pOCfRcW1ShD4kX721i7nE3R0oPZWfEHhMdASmCdzOxmdygXO@kWKV7zBpQzK@AP84K0DHuVbHjveci/D1uA3tORw8im1eH2@jBfSLnTqTnbtk8wV1z@ibfaOv9m3qHL7voe4BHOnysx2PVQLK31eca9y/R/IomMv1nTB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@cbZLdx734Gk34R3rLQgQjy@aMeDIZuIRGP3Q32nrw5hZHJM17TUNPkeAtXR4sN/59ubdw9iDjvTVLvDNx@g@U9xtZauslsNinDlhFe851uTWrqp4BbRR5R3oIz3/Br7VNu0v2j86Cmma1n0aFr60KEfsvOmu/MNmKtsm0r6NcyguXzfB2dZtWe22n3tS0VqqYpraNdZz5DDvY/OS4UwppprLL2JwRldA1rZ4wwyQS0cf4yP3YfGv9DyzNzabwxte/xlwTC5mu/bW/kqAToeyl8svM6JpiEfNzZ5G3geWaoQ67QPchMp0Kgsp9UcaCXyg/afiT1cQnrRguEDSs9UvakwoTWyb7FfioV@suRpoc0KED7PePGQINwR8g1mhfGdYc9JfJlx@x3QqfBnLsJGDw878dUkRzdvQ9Zm6PqKIR5zR2V/RfGxhZHioysj88icyYq1zbQ6fNDepWuWw39ZupufW7zZxfpZqPH82a9oso7a5b9f0vQGpo0b20GlSLdt1WmjGRylMZeSXAQZZg@kclpnAbAHO7f4s3sD5ukqkyNe@t2@2lNwo9uehnvedGd2EATM09sEvgbxm6HiaG@GpqvOxTm9XeBrUL5Welp7Z6IFPIQedcWuKP6Y6BQYNNsQt33Nof3FnmN@R@IsRivvs5HTlnb/nNvjhpGQniS2ebL0LvO2g/oOtPVjvDI3r0ktVCy6Pyj4NJcMqOI5t57zt1Y8ZlW4HQ6soSMe83Mf4GmBsB15cE3hzq0GUjH9EYQw6yu6O9/WHDKmgn4lRsbA@ZDW/b2mmz32fTnHQB0DgYdK@AOMtQ7j9KHiQg8wnHlaIM2O8pkiHnv90tg3vbyJ1os0qT1818IRHYfzD044KbHfD8I0W5zacjLe0cgo7Y2kYxTetnoWxcMdQxweXNPOMIKLx5VkMpGI8ERoYO8ZAOZB0eE0PLjCz705TNccl2C1Ljs/Z4t3o9XcqnzPakxaldjlJceKHzpGsTWy6GTZEU9@vqhc1hZj6XRsMXZhrLJczAdXdWCsueDKBGxXowcvb0ACZih8Byy6vRpX@cEcp0@H3kCp6oBydmqQzQQVPX68hJ9dOsGV/X//lx1xFhBmcA5oNSDYgSB4FNYcqH3z9hnPV@TesCwFzxIiDpADOj/Zkt5oMGBQ0OL4EUDzlp1un5TFwSJx7hY8h3yU90vBGxftCLgt2OWNx0vjb/EUGfupvEq1TX04MEBv7rh9J8OONdrxO7SDrXvgQjDDtXHy0EmxXdZRcf2UNnLTfFk3zWs6kYEl@fd/yY9T0XZusc3Wy56OUYZyxF3bMp1harfNIZTaQ/JJtU0BEkcig1QYoiUKmF/l4Qnc5EznvIAj094pJ8qGH3XaaByz9BaL4ZFiPDxR1brxxcbRi7fnucvaj2yQVf/DL7KJO0E46bt0peRIKeaBVO@RscLRRYgOYmNMWhxJPEN/r7sm9rrf8vYAEimcyXC7u8djpmmJXkMnVelgps@N4r6DOLqpnb3jTgM65EoMq97ScSfaY2qgtMTTo4YDHQy8CULNe11tMT7kBpP0scuKkCEeGVPAxY/F0u5vPLqDSRZH7DPrI5Ol27gjGXyckDqeFhvU1r0NNYXwtqfsptoa0lr/TT6TL9SoOovN2lqdXLbaMfHU5vkPF6N8Ln0xWtm6zDoeUS8uRt/l8u@A6ibM5RafZrHnbe1v3i1m6rnPnx1lzCTpPlblW7NATCzeHe4ebh2fNE5Oj6EV7j3xs23aAyWQNchFtMe4b@p0HhboYmuq8w3yx/cBeDzOFhW2hvc0JBKR8PZZAhW0ltLSIneGRNNE6i8kn5feUUPxswBCpnU15nHULgwT2IbAbEg1rPzQwlO9TKQVJxOJyzSU8diBfMLgBrg5spRIJbEaECsNxPpKUrGHK/uMh30Nxb6I5XGyPZsLghTz8zv343kV55Lg/ndSbwsGyt@@3hzL4/UmmEfqDaB@qJdmu7G7d3q0NZkMeIyeJHVrlaLYN86FM/Y0bmvxjmLSERuREI1NNYlJlIB7xWBGl3C0VPdWhWoJ4dge8MTEoVR@KRIwJlCmhjeZXFY5LeJxKgHqIFWs1tS29q42ChXRG6ND6O54FX0hsC35qL2CZySBOUr3UmTw41UDsQpyeV3vkIS4kNcxJ6z@pLweh1XDMRr0Vkr1wFDljzoOg//QqOS58pdsxMRwJl@yNMvDV1dhztb3YRNVPkaxRU4IaZGXXfLLi3ciQJk6VwrN8Wgrlti5D6O0rlh4AFtA78O8apV9HJp0TMgTJr5@cYszCIVf/0FN21awNnT8yHDxMLU3bhG@3e3jGmpnXDUj@R7muaGBAxUAhS7j2BrB5ACYrUuynh/r5yQ3xQlyb6gkI6AjToz6WoLDbjSHjITYCF3UcXSQlFgbUXG8x4YOiLGG7oBO0oHhm9/6QspJhrYI833CaYNJUeDJjK8yppgUQVinNnuiGIbS2zYMqx944kWCI8xOCGds7Uk6DZTraQZzDA3UeXcVbZlkfVhlrj3EFfd6bCaJV4RVcqX77kAPAc65W@FCzf70j/@M36dw4YL7D4V7lFsH3x8JXxfc/8iLkWXw/RPflwffH3PfD1lsstlD5DPlxH4uKsbL57cgtt7b3UPmkBEV22egjEKkR6mBfKQZQANtAA19Q@2G4DyHoFkCPPHzt9DswCvQ5qiyoJZC@an2ZRyPB69ms6jR48wuQ9tu1RG3oNJp4Y9DvCUDFKtsqVhalrNQyPSNh5CO7PVwnydHmEisgpyL3GhW7UOrjbvymeS0FV2tlaq8vbOLyg8F6YNf0EWAjXDl/5xBGtzI76eAuLpIFl9UknICk@LgFJNjKKc6Jmcf0PDi5ACQBAYb3pknUCFNQSrgTUMduaQFjb1JTQvvMkJLj8rvSvEQpQERx413OUx3sWDnJm50D3W6TLgZpDMEO0awVWkeA57/wC7cC@NS3OnBgJl@NYcdDXD/wzkXfXDOwkOMszdMxKfvh8DasOfHhok7fLehtCyez@YLWbmUCHGoJFBBebH7fgaU0GFBALRV7cq0nMbG1u7Lg8PjmZsSCDI2DRZjsfpa8iKdSZ1f@o6YX@5Joq5vZ49fr297pAyXKlj/RohgEXy6mPNymy7pA7mf8S2zs3lTxExGcu5rEdOKU3qb9ojMYg9isyHADb5VbybXeOLu/vxyrX5hRGey/zzv9phoZgmZC1wXDt0dE5suJhZx19sIfIJ3yjkZ7xBIXgruRvKPp3B/EPzwXQf@DXXBhQfeluMIHUX0TyJGMg9sRoa6Z7I8KzrtzwvmlRdkjVdUGYsaZNiOzOxhCJeGibrMXqYnztr4RDrgdiHvKjSHQzoknLnliG4d8Wnmw514GLHrB1cQiLP3fSidrrUit@KYqHdSyT8imnEsXXPjiYghIKbPLM1COo@e5PfBlNr5iPmHdBzUA0cZuv8lThfl3F5G@EUIzLuvIElXHhwOgW6HpsUCy9im6rmOQE9im0PIoo2TrJfDAcB16XGk4mihguaUhsRAz5hXlHM85C8okRl0ivFRItNXRx2tByNOPJEC0fSdLAeXJSh42h90pda8GqCpyeorUAdsmsIa3jUwSqxVyBtUkNsQ2e38YOMyAsgwaSuxyq0RsVPDu9cGG36VxVI@ZVqJVCzD@OxIXFlD67BkXMqwjT7uWiNzRrerkRoWPoLMB/OuZg8yWCsYZjgLvcA9q2Gu@aZ7K0KUUc6VjGZ01FEcjwivXiKdIDx2e3YTS0gzLE6XZ4irEjrTt2h4slBxhVAKbqCYkneVii/nJkVDpZLpOxE87gUTDcjx2LX3wAkqQrw7UCwWH9I1JA7LMPLGL@JGynHtBEvXcbi@ZQZLJslOAQ@KgHkIgnbJpdF57zje2hXP1qCRMNQxOvj4pFnsXM5kLsFNmSTYItooN0CbQuteIgLzTkiySmhBv4C/VSwRvyExI25KXKRsI3QTAEDNjSY51euTfAFaUK1Z/Wlw7DokYDhVK5VV0RqT0r7CgC/W5ghEQDtHint6P9BXHNgBqqGMBqgNW@1oIC@fv1INQwUCAc8M8EJIZQhMZidS3l2lqeA2Msohyou4I04AQUEnbynbit3pJqhri9kqmbuq96DWfLhAvaYrNJtx9r/OZrLVu/iiXhtnQddM1OOL/ZqcLCwlk4vGUnzRQG3r6VO0kt0vgjLXzMCkcwRA6UU9UQV@BuWvtmhUF5W1@GKnll@iFOCFae8dJPjRyWbuFpX77OJTUJZSEGJzoRNfdOgCkVwmI99D@bCHLGZTwDN3eBMG3UCK2S9qySSWIbPYxAL8mL04TtKweXGcJYNcVej32d5AdLcpVcxviZmbUzkBRfCqP2AVccASG7maHnBwR1lhXtwD6h/P@BVud2W0Sq864QmVNBnz9YJFyGmUuULIxPkNLkDAURyIiN6UkkiAMPnNb6JyiTHpWakQN5PPirlqMlaUYeoNc@boc9DDs0uSLd1dbKZvmJqOnXeVYubj5eH14eG7xEWcVVgsunEgycvSD6ySZ1/3WWH5Bz7st/lEo0vZSDS7JD9dyWY/fPgAMw74nNczdRAf/JM4T8cuz@MrjNVXVpZSpfJS6nmsGSpYIp7PJ45Zll1ommY5nQ58zT5dFxyP8s@zZ5QXTOnhn/Ewkb9weB4EEaHRb4VTilF2saIoS8nl/HOjCkWr4KfAZHDibxm@MisW2RZ@/uZ//5s//Zs/ob8/pe@/U9g1@wSf6y7Df3J/6oTcCrpb3U94wQpMLWokF6xYrFiIHf8QY//JPk@YXH@28h//5OBj1I3W89kzG55u9GO0VI5yJzjAV/B8N9F6dA3BSvfRcbZWq4Fz5T/@r5C@/hLwYMx4DX7qRQ9XaRytp2uU5HO0XgKHnM9Dvv/3L34RidZH0U9RWZajY/prRnMyfspP5aeMgSMrrZQl03zulXcU@nhhWVnOXwTtGWpubFo/uA/5QLsyMzoJSm6fq5jgBnJ8CxzelVt68vzDJmMqDLX4WV19PkPwvSn/USYNn4zoBiP0pEdeFaLlWqrJs/d5NRpyTFXY/2Wi7r7/G@EiUe9eyPS50r2coPpFVC4vHzwfffWHBYX2iBgNaOdnzqbDPKr7HuZ1evYtcJHoj7XakYt/r1v4d3iMfz9XzLFn8HkCf/QPH9@Lv08oRAQTyOznyW/RXSPR8@j55eWbPv3Z@Ldj4F/rI/7tfcK/Ny7@nbTx7@gN/j1UmUh0bW0tmkwegWooePZrPqfwzWSawufxLqL7nX7Y8kHp4HmERdOXyfT9/Xnmh1GyWhX/oDRVfR9@uAuKdXmfTq/9UE8mz6l453VRzrX0ZR3KyotMPz@sAeLk2vnaWqZZr9fTlz/Uz9cmE4l0z58nsZ8@h4T1y/PzSPQO26KGP0v403bwNy9JWfLiYAGjcwVcjJz0EAGMLnRHfyT6Ye1DPPks@Syn525y8rV8/do8CP4PDkYQoY1yV6ad6@f6cgckIsupp7lxbjzKDcwDuQNOFf5yA3Bque4o18sZOUOWx6MJVA//Dw5M9/WBCdhMSOmOci4iznXh2Ts4eA34upD3FfxpuVxuBIUc5W7gP6ejoKbbpuj5QzNxETln0gcVRv@MHMvkYplSLKZdFkvWx4u7@3zpo5SKNS/OY5fVaNa5uMhy7Yjll6t019j9fbO5tb/ZbGaRj9YWk8@T6efwqdWTa@LxLFqvPrtYTWP7cf7LNKPZtWcX9UIa3aUkNFIewtayyW/8BCjhWX9yEYEJ39kZfs9ub265ixzkujg782PxJ4tB5KIg@ABodm76CQcDTfP39N85@M/r//Upi59fJhiL392vxemTwL9E4u7@7l781hPxuPDE1@APA8CPSe7u6@gkoDtwnccTl4n7ex4Gv/HEGkdYxzzW6pQ4AIQOG@W5XsSqoOHVFuNioeziYpTLJaotCPHN68pnWnNJVGk3ymIL18lgNiAvJQikuFytLgv3SrlaLQu3XCpVq0s@VA48wglAqqO0q8jo1WgCi8C5P55Dmwrd5xiLd9QuXuz9zLJgYidXcp8/@0HNZkezm00ML3z@fAEdKYZ7UWqVIoTkyp8/Qx@MJWDSt2@KVdAKTOHkbB6dMjiLa2ul5Xq9tAzuUjmRqErni3e8EPFesiIn2P1i9lJ1JF5GmGzFonwHS1wuryQo9D62mJWqLLrGntWBfR34sLv7KFGSLRcT8dZYTbDlUrycrIi/2pMEW8vWl5j4Oz8vJJeXVpaeX14GKgJ2@OqdUpPva3fKKk7376ttcTEibotTnj4tVKCK5Vz1ItJsbjZOGk28YV6SUJpajGEoyY4Irv1ZduycjDPFyuU5lvvyIhZbrT7nbVQusmisKuDSMZBCrFyh6kVhBqh1cUPsCIW0@K7KS/nCk2xx9F1pKwca8@cl/Jyfn5fz5eQSSKmlSuXy8pJCPz@hNOeDUfeS7uippc/lUvEyjarI1ai7BIWVVwrRpYhFO31WcqyDi6U2GrueQGBfcVgL17UdVde9yyhvTVvv3GodFbAf7jU2tk5S@TVAmd9ubKTyx6frURm9xcBP0QX0H201Ng9OIcHh3lbjeOvF7tut00MId2DAA2LBZ3CoqEO1qd4Oh7fob6r02dAc5epKsaymBZ9R96df/cFPv/rvfvrzP/7pz//gpz//01//8k//AL5/Cd8/5s8//jeVIv7@@pf/5H/@6V/9OQT@O/j@W/j@H7/@5T//Bf@S/6/h@3@Gwv5afENw/AukBGx/9Otf/slf/PqX/@hfwPdfiu@/mP7@9M/@N/7/f4k/dP75T//sr/FHeP7gjwHh3/3Vr/D/T/7q7/7tr/D/f/nXf/dX/8Pf/dH/RI4/447/51/@G/77t3//D/72v/mnf/v3f/nA7x88@vvLrwj/5e8h5OvL@TV4vqZe3xryy59Vnt@GGkEuxFR/@g9/@uf/ALj1n3Hffw8@@Pej/tD3@DFJmpqlk0HgHzL2OQvKT@75Zx8UUP6PGArB7PMkNgrNeaG//uU//QsMnoD9B2EMOXkWdhGB/dz@EGD/lV@wMOwf/vSrX/z0F//tT7/6s59@9UcoxNLLlVQjlZa/MLsBwOJXwCFg6WvgAFBew/XsJ@xJJA@OJ2todIjIyQ8fgKRPwAVK9FKkWABfRK6TW0Y3JIQ5yRKfFSdxrg/fUWS5Aj40AyRh2EjyqCRErSdZrVZLRkY1iCNQ8GKaEauXcf6Ken8N8GIinibVLINOyUbrhAVS1pJHrLlUG/GESQyoEwaGBcKgI0nOS8lybRMyrI02GeJC5MnIB3h@qNXLtVEd0f1IRQAcyXXIEqBqWLpR/Ufw1wgnwEdGmz9CUcq1ZLJehpAaVZVySzUpT7lIlaO6JxnVG8MZQyvYs@eMfSfJZYnPv4CUTEDjbzKAfkZWiGcQf5FcEtWhf89J3yVMD@00IvrwMB7/DIMpvQAAvOk07meCbzqNpXkO0SOOKknZwiPJMQDlksJc4wfQyJqMJKl9k@SB/KEMX/dZq4c8iA6rs7i4CK61ulSQDkCRZ/b1quMqNi4NkBazyqRSRcJg3EqiLh6Sqr@0uQS/MvxvPaEtnpwcS5HFGA7fMeblkU4WzGUzSqX3qkZ1WaKSJwkuEg3CuXpJ6zugFy6zRCRONyonaL6oWqC1RF47vXVzBDpgSpJScqnCzaRiOvneXF2t/Sgvr0TgSf4hXuYsrhWGZsAX/GSwdyFB63fpNepp4AQVoxSp18UaFZMj9eOtE0hwcsDkfC7DQHG8W17JLxeXi/lCqVRcycvLpcpyqVgugIQq5Yr5vFxZXq6UKyv3UKDn0M9Tq0ut4lr97818/qu/N@8zPxQ/kfo7Nsqww8M36ftIfZROZ/NU5JpcXKmOa1AQCorUSXviOvL4Lg2KJjZP5IK2ON3hzhsoWuQujay6AB8WWYiwBQiCD2BGCz0Ty8a7B1WxfoZX5fM1NEkuAjMkIhfADBxbxAp/IthwT0HaPJW5s1gKnDl0Rk7wmMg@ZADtYLA93HzomuzE5Jvc1tX2AxAbff5aqA3bBH3z58OsK8Y1j9rU8Aq6tutH7Sh4x4wz0Nz@AxCn1gAPhaj27w3D1qAFBUQjIgdYhx9bN815ACvs9PCBWr72j5PhchydJwPwo90XOyeh58lWY2MnUmLrB/ubU4@iACqyva3tE9@7wmO9pEUfxfutvb1pr3jgnOEJK66kUiD44AefKfrQM7P4gwciZx4eEdVMLiWDgG@O1bt0@r6l4hXix/yS9FFXNx05FuupAxjBoI/KwMa4w7Vn6jA9Wsxt5HDFIPsZpzdNNV8cs0UQeBWY57G1Yr0UlYpSuVbK5WFQobvbu0Y1WoIZ33nlsjZiBVY@v7SiznK1Uoi8xu1bFZkfLdCcyA7MRwZ4bzWei3YjttqBucmtQacmWviOmKHFHgyEBwah09Z6fRB6t6YPANPESEtRGHy/9QM41PDHfTzA5XlQ2EyMPgseufWtPL75hvl2HCEKznBfL53p8RaLaWBxViMnKILp1UEMT3e18LZ9OmYFYzs/dkp346sgkCuRCC6QaV2Wi2TI7JWvlIvlSiFfTpUr5eUiTBOLKTmfklfKKxXgkJxclkvlYkVOlZcrhWUQxxBbrKxEoiCytG42C6ONLEn01Iw23oK5hteJmpl@PRLlZgMY4vFla1HFDxiWmVQoX@QYJJQiuL91aVST8GWEOXzVnyxFJIW1WXR7eyO3vS1J6@hBG99GTpI66CmWc7mVdUlSKWYDhow8JOqjb6uEWqskaejZaGxvI4Yr9OTLiEOSrnkM9@ieZwXADPQUCqT2StJHH10OkJu8RGVK5XJPLre@IUlDXjw8AQhwDe5bpsJuoQcjMNE2j9mAOEl64SXKARmkIw4nstrx6ttoSNIu9zQaiOIlVb7IK/UKPQ36QCIbfMD5ktQDR8@G6bsktcCJ/C9JbXC1xwqEDcCF5/oMV5GkMa8H1kSSRgSttK8l0OZEOOQD5dnZUfpuR@3xz9jmzzZE7UKUNhpubbdevGj1ei173Nh6cURRL1/uKFfjod3qtUTCVhM@JqaCqOvBePqjYlSzqejzo15BlDEV1Rw3VSphU/kIJROfHmY0aL7EqJcQNW9FSCCEzwCAW/hZH8BzXWnxKO9DUfQctVpSFVkWu043ToyrpOjRYok7FIdx5Rmo58vSKspTswtK1bCcSBefDctSaUVaXYKn9EwqgHMUz8VyjEmxC0lKgGR8Jq0UpdXYs2fp2FP5GZNWKtKqtLIiJar3qDjEE3fd@Cg1quUgIJtdw36MPQ@eoKcIJeNEHbmZHRV3Y7TT6bOJz9raGcDhGUw8ILc/HLB1dkuiA7fLe7uLm7V1kBO5qoFnnFX0Lo6io0i9o7gKTDfW74arqwL2vtqrnSOCz/izlpbO6mfSJQvnW1zJQalOjXZ@ZW3t/PMl6Fo1uTqOwiiSL1dHUToRsbJcjYNqn6g56keucX3W0S72pFnLcd1r0RkOznNPSnLqLt1M3@uK4y7KK/nV8@HieVq@fPIk97m3Jn1fly4xe1TJ6C9svAOBVoUwj2RcBEa72geIZ6tp/g4GuVxKZHCTd9PsNumedfYhJOkwoVUTDSuxOL4khe8oicdiK/lYLBGrAvATCBYtRhzhNakE0hSatJIHla9qq@4QFIxc9d4ri58NVzdLciR6H@ngVZvLlUj0LnJ/d79W98bvV2w8VpJpz/uUsV4SZh5ZWkDApYcn5Epn6s9Zo9boHTWqArSxQfMD4JoLfvgonX3yrcsUybX6D/x5UcdlO8gnQsXnS3nZtWQ9W6/XLyKSJEUlz8ocLxdhVoFT7x@jdFMa27jrDg06Lb36GgmmrHIN5Pwy8eO@pt@VC@k67ZCJA8/fR5NrWVz/ytSzRK32Aa0OR6KGKZxop3ShC8RBsS5KOIVRmXVc@WHlh/IPr08PTg@22fPcanm1zElBy/XPUyk5JseAtM9hZNOOtiJR67NZlH80Xlajq1assBwrTKhOFzVx9jaOnBA/R6v8eeHy8hymJ5cJ8NVq@WdysZxcXpVXEtE6ngHMr0Tr5ICulS5EL6McwfIKS4CHLMJ5OVrPinB5RU5EnTT3QZpi1IlEy68/fIappXiJo5YnVzYrSrV4v3YP//X7c5h93dMk7J7@8ScLP/ccAP4R3PfwR/AJwYVhgvjLH9Nr/H@NfjYOeJmlElA8@qFWh4b9oflDMxqJVmL1ZDaGrxMW@wrEtAaVniWD/lRnCf9@CAKWQE9b8n3gXVtixTrM@tWlbDZ7kXiTB52lUimVS9HIb2Y/2SWYgS0tNFiMXzrCdSV6r7Z3yCQ28TYonDgvLaQ3jw82XsH8FJQl1cC34rGNg/0MRuGL24JTQm1dVWx9LN7cNkYo1LFONg7xzcynm4eU5ozOh1EozY9FLou7nVXx4oTUDZMzBZbP5YrZ3HJWLjK5vJpbWc2XmKKrMPXeGlnCtYhJGVVrw7TGXLONbyQo8UIDYTBuT4NpiaOusheHe5SCjoovLWxuvT5gB/t77zNeKA8/2dk9ZscH2ydnjaMtqMfrrWMmNY7Z7rHEznZPdg5OT1hj/z2D6KPG/snu1jEiyEZQXuHqBCeYr/axNWfsZN2xpTqk@00EO2b7WnUnwxXbUrJ4h95ksIG36qt4GfVk@NCAuV0nrFYeNxZgtjds4/ts29dKp2NH8GCa1mYLOCQvLKk27vSU@jlnhRWH7z7l7OIT1l7ej62wdm7fKKytMD0n/pi@PCgcsSdPnlwYUlVI40i4Gr5WGw7C7c8QFpRp9/uthXhpmS2BLptfTgQx@weHCznPt3B2dLIg@3FHmwt537O7vVDwPVvgW/Z922ebC0Xft954tVAKku1vLKz4vs2tjYWy7wMmXagEOPc3F@RcxCPWjal1FuiNQPHt3b0ttgRAiepELFos0DEVDISIDw2H3xKAJGdLS7d9E19HDjOc8RR0R/0StAc@AbWAmsc50vUyxZZMC34G6gCAIRntSI7Tm5/sXjslsOJtEjCCRO4iC1ihBawQwC/g@VSEY09qLJ9gEL3Q5auvcX4xTopJpw6dQvvOYWs4/teBGVJ0PQWdRoQUqniBV2ThXqCMd8mq06XtmAQqQ0klW0ok8LjT/uneHs/MgixMOy4RJCOPNAenaQE2qCL8YtUhlDcObxZqC6TVgtAg8CVjkfuJ1oxMtyaSAuq5sNAGBJPUvVH0FEOFKoVLgYgXPXwbNQBDNLhz4OLnvOLxNta1p7ptKlACibl1sM1riIuJNTbZygmGmRKlKJpv0P78mXm@C3fSa096jRjHLZDzYnF8vKQ1hE1g2IJ3wI4g6IAwpVxAjkkmITVUh@JC9VoAosOXnyf2SlmHjHIx9vQplWMNfJUYZYHpkpQjSyMIIhAEI/IhMr9oT6i4iYXsEi7b8zf0IhFxHOFX2rXG/l0IIFmnCzrVqn4v9JtzwVAdtzolkEVUt4NtDe5Cvgl@FI/AySnWgm6SYl6kXMJInDukmJpiXQiekqlNzQDOVe1AJnqsAJ2RWn9/k7cQv/iDwnkA1Rjk3io1GAiLp9h9idEXFlq2qlxXPSiQhwQFfItME0dCcLjH0x1tUrIl3l@QLTH116Tc3V71@IinBnYQnEZkxZkJ5xVRXQqsB0Az@AUy7L81QM9ZkiNLJgWEz2UCbGsSLp3mcPceX36hElvTtXjyzbVAsfxgLba@shq/XS1gWAtYBGoBIj4OeJMATT@TrZmfhwLGQkJBtfl5KGAADXgJ@vgEgq9ID0NukD797elhkF6d7srQb6EFuVTgSSa97UlvZ9KL3RdCFAZTgvwy@8xa6JJL4MLzvawMjg6XlZMJu5NeMi3UmOql6foSmOcAPIeikoMhA84KY5QgGQev31YG@AqIGmtsN3f3t04mYxFfxmmKgvfx7caUR2ISTBQI4504ehJ@ieJdJALXN@OHPI8U0bN5fHK01XidgvIl2FrQA6Z1APgRPWGiBvdeDhBqqG0YjzspFj9usKUEe4olSzFhGUDPV2ehm44KqB7MsTO08pRVjoP4/smeFMUeGZmTlRRn8QT7fHEBQ2puhckD63NhUDBWCh02Lqygssvx@DqIkPKegNnnXZMrGwgJ7KngrRNzM7vK5diyXWCu2geNe5SzZ/FTve5xbKNh0TuFaJk0KXOq9IJslC3iHgYYFydVm8e1SBobkQ8wFLsxhOFwTvarJOnnyJ4U6ylYvCwd9VvL8iWNdrIsaV6WNcp0tgy/ESY8mC5Fpk6a0nUWpuVaCh7GFJEHFtpNDjHIjkS4PSV0q1HcxIv33cQq3UaBMqUJI7nmNptxR9W7@Jbdod2GIR/VZUeA4QdjMzySOhI6JiMFeVB/mozgL63Hu@9g1JlCSC/7rdEdanHKMRLxS@a4qkWlChUDbWL4tslwhvjC9LAfmhUPNYVKnFgVWvG2gv3BQ3Y@cRENxzF0@qk5wSCeZ0N9Np0T57PNnDi8b2xeEu@w7Zy4q@FgXglAMDwQI47LzYkxzIN5Cfg9LkHE5XmIgOdhAl9exhPzmx761WSLhy7iIfqf2ENV3CqzexBiQVAuBQeG2jq6qQLTtjW8zngakX9gF1LGR4nQ2WGfrRIBJylOW9Om0XuYBCI6/EY39rLRKr6vfPSdnC8nUiGEIYx4UdxA0R/CyUJIoYRzkET5i6WZZ@l0fNTIgtN4g/QZPPpudGB6FyQwrUfgMTaAxcb3gBfwJiI/xmfmOV0uQLc6yzgUjvZ2bH554s6mh6C9SsiJMEF/2@zT35p9OpQ/9smflXWNnU@W4zIZ8q9CQFBHr4P/rIy8Uk/mlvimGoe5RlWvH2BfvIcjlA0/fz@ZrY9GSCCfp7yqEHoM@EohgbjCiL5BvlDzidPB81IH489SjaVlPw2XeEFvIKt6qPARvDmg2cRrNJtNuj@t2UTLUrMp8Rxo4MUBLzzois7G4zKgpTZNio1LaUVKSel043hjdzetGVKK3whbkxzXtNUmXoMkpTowUapJJLCaCNNXdasmic1SisMotfRwHo1QHlDBL2dCQDwXehl4@H7ML2fXDlfJ/IoqmVOZBXf2fUVuR5QbHmV@LCebX37lZbQBflfFC69sVUNBw@@6Fa90xUsPJs7ao0lfFIHn65Clz8EbDniR6NHEMNHWeFUAvTi3xsjaJ3l3f0gzV3WI3o6mHkQQcCrnPumQ3pDB6B6ojir0LDIPZaTgXj9RsIyoaYjfPQWNX50QDGiT94GI8qY826SDZsypogaCxbSw8ucSXhcCDXBoWvDrXxkCbv/SEHDjtSEY5Ik6cOOdIZiiKxzi@hBw0QUi8AT2loI7CAfKSBsM0XATPpQuNLmgWDjkY01o1KfISenHKYoQGR0vc40LvImktCpB1R26rGT6whKEn3dnSeIyMitk6dZcLGZIdZiHdO4tKInU76CRQooYimZHlAbSpiQmcSWE0sqrlzD5DPGOJ2JQfZ4KM7nVExFBTVJ@@mC8Ct15UpuYXiBFYPLACxMk4Fam8JuoSLlPrPoqSNBiYSiuuM0pN@51fLDgYQyeopaIPDKT@v/NPCncJP@ZTpX@v58UzUx9fs9TmUemMN88W/kdTgv@i0L/XxT6n6HQ/860@QdU8mmUsz1@Sl3/ohr@7eoXybwxDBt27wZNb/mfo4f9jhSBlW/SA7xSn8uP6QJfHp89NPnwsP4zR@nIb7InndLZttloNE4Gsn30otFr9BtH78G/nttLnl0tr2/err9Y7zQ2N3svexv76ptyY3nPevWu/P5F99NHFbT3nYOX33/SrXY/8u7Iuj1TD28LatlpDIcfd3fG7s766WDjuPh@5Ta3pRe76@rHTd3ZfH3y7tXJi@Jx8vbjy8OXnwa5gXPYzSmVQWHndentxvjMiBRvtNPO9p52MDjubJ3mB3ub2vvt5EZu77jyRs7tbd1@X9i4TRZz2V3r1cGLo9Or1tb3@tHu3vvOxkdTKX28vrV2s51Kd@Pq6G3koPBG3vl4cNDbylde7GRvN7tWJ5ff0e3i1bujw/XT9zv9V8rWYLt4Wnl3NT4s9d@8uXH3k73ls9LwtbOcNBpv3uRfGS9ubraOIi3FPLEL6pn5RrZubw/NymBFfbW/0xu8sWUje1B8mzwenNxubq3rH1dGhdP3Z29ul4/fD1@/efn9QU47Pm5tKSWr1ckfX50sR9qDwm7y5nTrtKy86Jy9Gdzs7hTfb2Zf99X9RudQv37R2/nePD7c220UnKEh723c6O9f9K9eX29u7Orm4bVuNJazRf2k8/7gIHL6UmttqjvvnJeNq/77bHH9evl9smO9OLn61L9@uX58elDOjw7HOXPDOWrtdEebR6V8OdvWPx596pqv5dM3ydLN1cu89r7xyY0UPo2LlT39vTowXibbve9HH/Vs8lSWN77f/fT@/fHOjd1qGKcf324fXdmvO8aBc5A7evnqdUu/LrtX1vfG8bHczr1Qr18nc0pkdLrjQBupJ0px5WSw98YabZofj3a/d0qfkjdn1wV18/robePjUa51a1jvDHtPG2zkOgdK463pbg1HL9qVm9PrHX3v44HzPvJ6Sy4Wt82us959u1x5l32R7F6/eLcuH49y@8ZRd7lk7799c6ZpW/13p5@O2sXtt1Z54Bq9N59OB1vJrb1R/5NazrX04/fXRuS0eHx0mL81XmkDd3vn6HXJPcjtvT3s7IzlxhtVvjVWNsbFzZFdKpxtvrPfX@8YVva99nF4mFNvkp33lrv8Rmt122@19uBV5Phl/3T/8O3tbrFkvxgY2vphObe/t7Ox3@ssvxrvvh5u7bWuOi9236nvrJPSdX5r/ay0@e644J5cv3Ir7ZtB4bCcPNEHbu80GXk57A9XDs/sj29H3y83Bi21cKS/N8cr8mDjpZUfvW1sHXzqXR9a5r68nR9nT/fMaz336eT2045TaoyT5dGpOzDdE3lUlN9ECrefLPel9fLN8cH6y4PvXyrLmnamXB2/7eQKp@Ws1rcLu6XSC3lruzv4OKio8qfN1wWlMOgnnb3rbGejc/r27Fq/GrwaXLUj5YrTXt/9fqiYW628nHu/3t0qqnvreyeyetp7dby8uZ87fNc5PP04OulsvBuevj3QcltXLyt7veV3R28rr1a@P3FOlDPz3St7PzIqF0xHLlWKt4XjSvmgbx8Xzq4q7vevrkrr@llLfrmbH6jbmv2uPC5fW5/6t73bYzXX6r3Y/KgcdbdAkp4e5pTi8Hp/dBwpvD0Z3KxY68n31@1X7wxZL59pK9mTj1eV637/1e1me/ms8emjUnxxpVaOt7Mtfbv4Inm08ebwqrd59qm83Mmt771V3o22@u77yJsdbfOqcnZ9MBrLb7aPx4NGztCLN8dnxZsTc/34bOe43H/dsrutnas@yIbB@PTqdnizo670R7flV/2rt0pu7115w3CWD3ORl@ruoHN08updI9nNqxX35uD9vnVWPhsVX5fNs4p5UNZeNbovRm8Oulu5FUs7OxmdbvWz6xvaoAwy5VA/tTcO3ux8f/bSykXyRmn904ZZXPmYvBm9L51lD5N7w/ftk/zgzLZ33mn29rubw3evjhu7yd3W@MXhtXLwfqt4vL@x4bxMbmsldbxTuHUaGwW9a0acwfpof2RblcL313s9GAnMTqXz4qRwZjiNRvd2t3y81Wi8cFq7L5XR6EV3BcYI/GydvTVrkd/w@8gi/Coy/lD4dQeRgdNrmSOQl/yIVoQO0UToEE2EH5uh7dB8p/FvskuRk/BpGHqPIjfwDFugrLGOicpDhu3693vilf0pNjAhuYautmnRE9G6ttYauuhzTB1@yV6Fh8DorU/qyNJNDd@Ggjez45zUVvlJM1BfMpEDgw3GON901QE/o6PhC03EdZx0mTt/bwxdBxhZaLeZ926sDF026b8p6wMoEJbRS9Ptoj2WTre7utJzwKF3yPUhcuzffo056JqCxg/MQt5rKnKuKLamorpKhTvB97Dsv2C6ya@K92YcCigTY7rqAY1UdN2Diq/adLQbVR/T3f9qJxPhOz6/ahdkOAy3cU@G0ZWIU3tDQd1Q7akNoBZP6K20Zpee41Ucz5eyYokVlaGmYrc0F9/W2OSvDGjyHL09b9bk3kM6cikWaLlihJoNXSbKnQNlhL6pVEgx2k6OBwlckT2qhqiiersNl5YsQkn7rhj3hDAvWQ/j1ga93xXqCdwdTZ3AawKthkArWpCeWbP/zqFNjj5QNcIX67fe7Z40xQsi@BZDTqnHd1yGqFz1fFaV1yBUflHy2W2ZuMMAio9mR34XL1T1xuS8LNG@R9weCa2NM@xgtyW9jRiLjtgs2o1yvnzJdxDmaOueR3A/zVPOCU9DpXoaEHRBbKjweeAr0/ENmhxktr6IuGurKgHQbk7vGMjUZr/fMe890DItXTGu0VXlW2VhvmC3Q41F1@SH6oGmLL8uYv8kzRGw3pDU3wYbFFSy/WYhALEh1mvmUwO7M@23xzS8hf2s0T6GefizLl032/EgesnbcsPrlvBy4vBTWR2gJbGLO2tNe8wzQvNMvFoFENynQzJBNbzdqqFa1wJqIDra1BMqBfBt1QvC891qUM4Ue7y0PKsnxA60A2h@UflmIIQ694t1ybN6WBYCvRPhykwkDYjjbSECZ3aJuaYFROgKjoNhjHiE706doQrf6eVzEeN0Os9dwj97Fvas8o272KFUNHuiCElgN8YZ@lTh/EIjaN3vOphVwHrUULiDG5tQI15kGszwMZxpyeREO4WQn2tIN5klidrxObEghvwaCdIL2hMM7YmD1uBbcVmX7@DitI5MkWgNMvr82e8w4PW58dA7xAss4b8bFhmccybvy4KgVc/vdULfTTEBUXypej@7lx65uwcTcPPW0kaqHgeB2cSXZFgMgsSWJcviDoLwty9BMDY2lV3IqydP4pDqnOCy5Uv2lMXltbX4SjpOQd@VEwm/M4rk@VDyUGIQ0vU6i@eX4gUv8TImBpSFSQTL8xHkOYLlpbjsIcgLBHIRMHAVg5B8x8qcaycRl0OIfbyXkzD4qo05uS/lk/Ll2loZ93iGAqcS5@cXfamQzENijnohORnD0fKIUPjlZI0AeSEfGkdCKJaTBUDBs05ORgS5TkX4mYbzXL6cOzj9zpQX75yGN/hQcnyLn2qfl7G@yKl8U7rFwG25tgjENylZ9D6lIIyz9BKyOegI1CUht76Kh6ZS/H1aYtAC@lWnRsXQ4QiCQDFARPDwaCl29dhY1/r2wQ6Bu2Tg43VOMTnFyjANAYkCEqMMiUGEEA20XrM9sHw4GIrLCb7jmw9glMk@rjjj@QFoJ1T7vZxIjHHy4Qo34GvTenmTxhBO3zgkaO7truPj7dYR7pjd3X8BTbiA9Uix4Ner5hOO0a/ihmLw9zForgZFANnGJzSirrypJvPHQC9/gc1DLuCnsfOEVDuEYDyx0A6JLzS3qZkCGyelx0eqS3Sk1wP5AOVEFeYZ7FZlio7kGPNXlZb5W4To0BulJlKBw08oCogUQpqdHDX2j7cPjl4T5Q6bjb3DnQZihglmW7E7jN5zgR3EMFSdD6o@PSM4/IKE5nVSWt5LGeglvATLX4LGiQeATYppUuh0ibC@nOln4HnwvAQkUXxoUCqaHdWagxv3rvpgojLOHIS8FXmpxVAoyjRvJKQBb3Yk9ORoHSUd0dJUHSPmAmPTez8Ug8uTrIdvHWaZ9CI06rmoR/WIX2z@lqhCnl4Hi3zkDC1cHVY7Upj8SrutOnRrRkB9QKnqXcpESJYQoSBkfu0D@cHPpvhjr8BBb8OjQTfn672BmjupLIL2yGn3s3TckILEsXg60p2nVpJaJHLmb6edUB21SZXxocx4blc8tyvIjQtcdjWtkGmX51cTitg88mgeea64buxpZlw98beSU8t1odM7fbznhWwhXOpQg2Ez4X4h2xxPyLqnXpM99Xpx0BPnK3ePK2WCsJMamRhwgvFTTJg7HSBbfMa2QSdXaPY1tLH9ucdQb9FDIyU/6ORNMQieOKUJ6rQH54lPPEP1IGcgJpCGdFrmXGR3SYOKjy8uELK0V55ESNegU5jCKqAZIC2Cw2mirqRKmo6YKIYCUayKUdjueJ2cIIPBzO5MH@hCIAzlBw6DUwn8GB/PqIxOeutejVAjhwQ6K0VwXTWdhgQJbtcgnQbELdaBiqe586tRnq2GqJynk2n8BAyKOuGWuShA0M8w74FQL/Pq3HqH6uEdhsPEiVDFclVxgsI70Xt6yApyoRA6/ntwts9KpeB0MN46xZbzueDIMd4/xUqVyM@ykwX2BM6P2HFEgyJbIc/g1B10QVXXoRPzR0fDoR/LxqfFI/4YV33laonPYB0hjsXQ4LABvqO7peK7qHG91mXySM5EFkAonoTecu4N3gDYGyq2YrgqP2OJglys7GKGlBB1WNV2@BvQ6R3gIPHxFdUwLNgqNwBDSMds0yZJxEHpoKWHA9qNlEKF4Ua18RoAzRUH/RdI5gh24KKhzpnAC/SEQ93jDU5CIRKoR6ORhZORhmWkHje9CFee1JWTvRyV8mRPpiHNe18oFoDIK1iFaMzdkQVB4JlhhubjS@IFS16X9IED0T/PNDg7yPDJqTcPF2j4GDM789cu5xhjiLva4TFoJDYxESqq02XCOwNHEsA7AtX27BAciB6jSxqeCBefjSIF8Q3iGreFM5IRpEXQKEVDio1ch7t0xMViFL3gvzGZ@LkGvS8hdgaMxYE5/3ikgECWT3AIcTZyGgL7J4cYhXFAKXhHXcoG@w9GiMM/74bimzjEm4WjOyHmBYiAz2tJ7eLl52fS5tdC9FHKlB9Jmy4pRSVCfXk@GK@yAMPahcCgUCSPvEp5YKeHwbk3D5BKTwapxwo/kdvXFl5kNwM0QYmvLLpPiHthq5uHFBIPzBuVL1KJbTVCzQy1D1eSoBEFIxDPUr8XpgpBA08q8NK1Qim4zuyl8SQJxYhDv7MiR0D5jqW8dxzYE@i@mTM41zuvopyTvap61aQWpLcW65pFQ@NkXUW3CNc1Lc9WdiVUWe@U8URlRSKvnrP3Oxjg6OrmLb9/AQcUSZxclr7rpNh3HVwMESHhMcqjxjz5N3nWOdQhf6gFPdKvn19WOjTre3hfFWuHKNrD/I7pEG/O6@T4ilsaAmQEN42qt7mep1pYEOoMKD0T6fIJYXb22dlD0e2CvKat@nh/6F7ewxRwDGGpsR85HhqCPqn2BLAH9pnkPBYg4cPiq7vDsCEuEpJ5opN63IERyaQYz2oT1uDgAPWDjBjGImRn6Ijyo@lJpsyWYoxxfJicj8NLIob7oP9XwwUZP1gQJAetEYmxzl8z4lci3P@2K6OB7mYJzQ30LisPPx@FIib0t2LO0wPiVqAv@LMDPh8I6wZC0faUQTRsgQIPc2N@NDrFIPcH4YMbRj7yBT48mgcp6QaQcDK6aiIskHgJ86FpkRWaxMwWk1qHKGrxNpksNzUkGUJ87LwaT61zRJbNp3EZkDuT8kytJtAxOuRM1rgqv/yDVFm8/JnmqeHbP7Dhl7DyuGQZzLMsPBzs7XYgFNrA0lV@ckfeazYOdv2rrZh4J7jqmBjkZEy7l73VrrUsB4wci2ur0uoQ@zleUsVjmlunMJThhVNuhh2rfLMC6r2oln2g6aQ6THzARHgDlgHA3S5ovAa@dr6lure4f0AgcDLhwkK04oAebhpsbJqtoPSKOJnDC5CisjtQ@B4QZtiiF5i3FddRx2oWE2ZbOvwMFLztNwtT8izWMHtgqHuQ@hi6hJq5Um6UyGaoYHRyeipXum4ukkbbEcW4@Epk2j2CNgSXXgveMqFt/P2pYpJAdyWahj5mBl4B0FPw3dyM3tIKWSHn3UI1acetWNShLQ8qzSOWc5USCXtHjHCUDsfvTAbiiokIf53nKp7vcExkF1ulvamUfGJPy9SeDN4xJzdR8Hn@ZFgbL@f68j4Nf4tHNhtKaxpfs@9j3h4Puv8LyP7Qzo9sFs2jlq6MmXSr0D3LbGN5JVdaxbmW1jOIDbG34CU6IY1dHVn4UkzcGIDjuJdWV29UnRWwGd9qzhAAj90hVCkStWylN1A8wHhhlWE2oTu6aH49caI/iDJNfTKki@cmWDCjxpNpjMkBNjrBJUYVJKYIFuOCmgCpBT/PcMuzaVpsFRwdtTXs0WCA57K8FHg6Skm1MIGSqMdbiWfwXIUnFJ0uH4V@jJ2/5t9fhfuJTI2dQze/ZN4ChVSNUC2g69d46ateehw5ECy0ogMDNl/VgBFhiTXFZJRbCQAaxzB@ASrKamEoUA0PpGPuHqDVhjLkm4u9GKyiJS51fHBPyRIL7SkBkYD3TSFj0hVY2axnGYk18PWmnmc9xmPJahTn7sBExEe9JZ8c3v6FLt99skZ3gjG6sZPImah6u@rlKrv3AHEPCGo4uLMkHfN2DqCGaePaTLAjBUgvebOwx9CGClD4AiQ1HLIZjkuhavAN3pfc2iVUkOlo@dJbw4LwWq7qUYO/Ddlv/2Ax6ylvzQWq@BN6t7J4UVM3LrX5QgytkogFpomy4uAleIS4g@MSQ3yc8wMFTHKDsCaS0TTlG1R5QbnNFYQF6pxpGlJSbMR6aH3n06cUGwsvXg5OmEa1XGpck6sRFH14VkE1hoM7nIykeJKhlULge6aCtK9G8FfM6Gyeud@7YZQgsY6CPEKCAoPOvXA0bdzlUky@r1LObXpzEhfxoEfM8v7cvVgXBuJbPYepCP1f8mFi9buOlOL54ZIBOWTPkb9MBblxIvqlHo3N6/goNQbRwfA8Ul3MOtAtjPPkHYei6I4SsU4jBAzaYZsKrjs2kXZx7wYy1hzVYILUHNfQhsfv/0KFl3cLukAG4VcZAKbTCAgzVOYpuxRPZAbRN0omMR4mdZPxQ2sVZ9le@pl4bD3Cz9OH8d8Hl@QRHZqjVHOc8PalQIrmeIlI4G9PuZ@pLhXvt6jvTHmn6jtDD7@@D9DDr@8sPX9WfX2L8TuqCAwx9MA5Dk7Zn8GMGt@m7gVyO8UzhoG5YITafD@demjh216mUtOl/bOpTcsyHbx/eX4JeJ5zCkHxoXDI8xnPYxXcMEHOcvORXM5B18Mr0Z0I7@K2ifpinNz4Sjs@foE@qXPbthijKQAxV8ii73vTU37IICGGknCQJxL9@mFWXKZydQLUtmvaX1xjoayqfsGponwOxiixX/sE494QjlDVafsilMZLgoRKsHlJhqh3YLrpJBg2P4mgupCPk6mQ6mxuKq8RMbXYXelpQiR2pF0@Swq0bim01tQk6QzsGtIn/Hmsb@8dJT0G541Blt5Y0hulYSq22yVr2wbfiM0OhXUKjz2BCu/2bXPY6zO8KAp1QITlW8q7Jmr3qF2CVo@vSRziXTWr3ra4eFB9336cZacWg0k@nZ/Hnvv6kG2g4t8aoy2Z2wLioWFC7LBaWPB0p4XApL1Akt4HvuSGPm5xCLKnNgsVYBP5AYrwGi1xkP0RsdOcjL1BLC37GoikuK46sFzUrDVeBax@kMzCZZggIWoA3h1fpKws@KDzC8vZOFRaKl24uHvAKvNKm5tbSDqGOl3IloqmvtwjheNWxGnbDRQHc8fSbKq/h/bzc@Wr1zDv/wJrQqYeV6YIToVJLm6OBmUHj@YN8PWceLMG51SYgQPKfdPGueE4NRfzLdrjqHcptzD3oqkywiUzojh9mM/e4Eajualpxa2vQFPR0QFEBCUg1YqvneF6Gb5ZC1O/pumon5hPgB1S5fDeWV4Ms42rzF7iWUrYZltVOw6qrAryCpUzjscbRHf1Vgk7mtLDGSLM1D3R6xWH7NE0W@xrbX4qY@MQi2KrH4eazSfbWJoMtCXt@wFW2Oir7WuCxffJBNjTmpEGshlu2uwy5@NQsdHkYNosGXMiQsbzkeZI7MSZ1qOEgKpOABPn1WaVkBAwqp94FeQUW3n2OjTVeDKPNuvgKyFijnjdg7AZ0StZQ7YftJpkGMgr3yADw7MuTuhqDuEJTb9TrDvUURabVgbjUBJOVjbsQ8Wy9aTGLzGcqGbIMwHEBetkbAij2IZi@xjiNIyLkZhLmi@DV2agMasHgNMc2p9jhejrEw1IOUG3ieUdOhQU2C8gmuznceQ3x4Pp4l4LWxVTCEyTS6Qok1m0NBTPYjVMIx3GzMFmEQMcgiW@tv1q/4naj6ECZKDsAQGDx9/RwthW0FhJRRezT@jpVEtkZFEVkAODoe4qhmoOHX38@2aEyAK9MFHozhA0Ju974Z1Ux3EaxmdnWXwZANvNHtB2N9ybgBN1EN75vVWMkU6EqMGGG5hinGW6OAbjpLwXPOEyUfwE4/ZEHA6O3p6AqRi8MgEtPbhNwKUzXim@bQBEJx0XM9wMpfM22Cltd0hCtG/i5grcUzpEexDu8bDxiBg1CQpsrAsiNy3V5pkBt43NIfPGZ@DX4KpPEJDBXZsaZCqGPsKPshmrhXzPBxLAg7hDqHDLYU8NpQHxCwUHcLIdQbm94a2lChsFDm58dQtfh4g5ULbwRNwaPwMXZPizc@OrcGjzxSwR91S6HF4rAJ0tZCXj@@zjT8T8PuFN9Kf2P5HK7Nm6PFjOUGJvP64k0K6KWbOcN4HVqrTRIq7VcKfGGp6wgH4JoOfa5ZMarrXwXRtkO8NWvAUGURW73YcqQXtpyDCuTXTqaB0iG8zh0OztX2XuMEBfw1y5Am0MBy28kqZL9PKPadK6BxrJASQeoE5QzsHRS40knJYEfr7ArZ5kP@4k/L7Fs6J5CU5@ANC3I@EIKspE9ktBGPQHO5t86nTjwoumkDySBf3nIhCvKRH30c9E5S@9m@v9KV@@Oo1RfgRjIjCeTR0JQ4OXG9ridGva13zlCM1uJPldRSO7N64F8g3LmMiz6OEivxPE8ZUMzzgXvNaE@jMOLH3F/bKR1@MmF4Sizg/08INTAYH5Gl412LTs70bOcd4CEdbmFqisiMKdUTwtX7nkgt1nHm/NldsQ@dmgXPjolqB1LdwVeFsLUyY/12brXaFdTfCGgBQcgdBeydH8LkySXh5pQkNQvPB8jkOFT9Y8sKo47pQOh9zj9J@X0yOf4BXVqOe83sj5o1bj3BHk4W8Sboe26i55xxv4frIJ8tObS2v@Cxx@Ht1IYnBzapWNxP4uOmk14ju8Fqbm34zX@BxV0oWF8bdQh2jhbxMPbPIScbPoBjTv8DcD5jlvTM3yPMHY5V1/zlEVscmTv@4AhneGL1MQxzfAGzaGO27CX64XHdRxM45LvBMa6dNc@gB/z@t3iu6Y4iozGlh5IofWC79tJcbrgTx70e9awy4WBVf6IU1wQGX2dMqTri9yaGsuX/DnlCJw2nc4RBy8/ydCuwW9C/X5qRWAoiMrYoVfJDz3bOKIXmyj7gobGa8BW2qKbEUdvCuMsBK04B26zoZmVS9stQePIw1L1HFiqC/5K9@ZyCY3Jh4e7O6fbB01j7bebh0db1FK2sjvHygeWlmylDm3eLm3IfDGnIkLcSJntgbjOI449J4lnIEft03XZdsw3VVhOn6tQEplqEYeXHPP7z0cd@qo9ipPf8KVeTp8TzuNHQ2PCA1xqxLU75ZPwPnycNxJcOaHMZAupMJdrzreZMDfCxVBmQnCnMeg/MSe1DLpva4EIU424JBidt1b1ADFbGJyjRlGGr0DvVnNiD22HjSaHIL7EvwLEVABgPj/t71nXW7zuO638BQrUA4B4k5JjkIQFCmRijm1RA5F2c1AMAyCoPRJuAUfIAIh4Wl677TTmTSu07i5TC9JO@3ftpM0M30E@x3yBHmD9Nx2v93vAlKyYk87okYksHv2nL3vObvnglq3syKFibbXKnR8B3hOZCOxrhzuFWTvu2W1z2S3iaza5nYhD9nqDvpPUuI9waoBcW5waOUxCPWa7mIyCgISqLeAngKxp7lF3KASygelSrFcen0uDYJH7K/IW8ErmOS/op131E4/Nn5SnNm@jgFg8TjzkA2dEzYp1oIuPlqTa1AXIrQqhF7NnDzZmlzQX/@KLcgTDMildje@HKPx12vPfWkz6y/sY@HLN8OJncCOVY6evrEqpvPXZ7Dzf8Vq5OXMRS6yonhjOhFvOiEB1V7GeGJ5ZZm0j5Hz2N3jC3u8ajLXP77W7pZwRiGeTO9ajqKtiWDjKs0H8WhEE/lySvSOBr2jVv47U4dPbmuMLUDQ3Hi145dotWUc4TS0/FKa8CZQzwUq7ra2/typv6Zrq@2jSvtohrxncJGGa06q66pI025zfq4cNXC2dGEdX5r@omFuzFu0U3nrMk4ro8vZoe/MuGRI/Z0vBWNKmyBvY4mRxeG13BBzMlttm0SBK1cdhXiRo7Ia1zzafyG19aAHg8tSciJmX@JLXTMr2DcYiIrOBrQ9yIbHyEEZXMYmoXSHRo9FEjFZaBGbEPMC///F2spMQTbweGNk9RUaWb2xGnljNfLGamSR1cjS1dLEH5WOvH4JWLOuKpwC959aggW1vafef2frUB2@s6PuPbr7e@pbe4/U@1sPIGVP7T@68@7uXQX/dx483FFUwPy81xmhyr2Cod/utDt0O79aLt9QhDkSoPyGetjqqXcG7c4LmDzrfqu3@ZS/FPud8QaX2nnRGc0G/Bw0RGWWsVhN0F0RvzXpGye0uD6CmdzDd0TtyxPrSN48fb5ZItsLCoduDLj5bY94ENLjomclY7QB8ANIBTQtfpIl3Wl8Wiem5biopOPMz0v3IDCF9x@qrQfbGOlze/dwd@/BQ3Vv7wC@7n8L3eyo7V10G3PnEWYR4P297d17u3e3KIErUC4qvFsjg/VFVSgiOPVK@/nJBMODdVEqlG@OV@@lVKo/0FYRvlqe9AP3PccwpfDdnZ2dVslFe@ba1sE330OupvNtlU5jkEvLobpYIFwro9EIUJMo2lV2po6sZaHCG1Jvpq5hdjVFd0D0Oa808iy9E3sdlb6L14j4IE1xs5lh06iB0FXAjai0I9iaoggMy8v5dUK5AdTo9kBTw4vVE/0Fi26KY1aUI5e0l1afkGJwxt1@m8Po6gSY96zVTWTHIwbACyFJYAC8g8GEcet5ZxcvSdRNgZiMUfCHhLc54VlveO8UuUY0cJWEOxwI5JbUiceNhhQDHLW8Po@jY9bEuwPFSKEiPsGjk5xuV1@5kkoc8P/yxoavsgCZhl3wBFa2FiqCZzeYDbC3P22djH2VqWXxNhhEkE7fY02tJ90WiHt0LzxCg6UXqEZAZG/V8GdDO6rXDCcF4tQizNFMufUw5bbl4O9cthyUvBOhiHp71GhUmJL4TxdW4E6kAq@CBhAV7P0C3QoNx8TYEprBiUzljD@AGQkin/rIjWo0OJ60O04BkXUyz7zvfCcrnZwPilgqPlQ7o2GHoR7wIeQUfVCRmwsQYkhT8im@RvEYZtwWBG/DPVSGGGEFP9SdK9Rs4UFTFE0cIYr8fALVoxYZw11IlWY86wab7WtofEbR87fPZnn0THKEYrKR5nz054xKDOjZaYRuXk4UKhbNxlQTDu6QCvaOj5Rfqn9wq7axfedx4aMP841S6QlvC61jfrxgpUR@ZiGRHJaH0Z0kbUC90gRpyp8cYWmtz8i7Ja5yjQwYl6ceMN@bzarJ42vVaHqf4mW56ZR4fl7jUgWyN6EphJFkgt0tr@qaZJ7KNFRWEAR7J1QWPevqlDzhNPv1Jsa1x1GoQo/0cR8h9Ro7rBrp11jervFBD3aWlPBpPNwGf1bHIpcZRT8ZezxKH2Tu1HIb2ZKGosVkujOjt@i8xlzJSqvmOLx0XkXQbS9GB/v35dHdWlg7Ph5eCtv2QmwvVbdCLhkXH0sWrsuj/WgBWj7cXgkttD2fjJgPySg2M9PN5MxfW9Jz/gKKH0bGjtYeoMGzFyOqGqQWtUm/ix7iMnwpDlWjAlkbTcAQPTzc3jk4UOkdvGVbg7Kw77X6bbIvxW0QcV/Vno7YDpk2u6JhmkyYIMM86ZQ5m5e6ZBct5tjOS9gqhAfJS3@YzcJE7QXJZCrWEXyyEAuBhte8Ieqec2t3pvcgvy6I53XUhFLBoFkNTMU2c4kPH3ayT5tM0G955o39597QMDOdqTjroqvq0cxGpBlhPA5aT/DlO3783mf@eE3TYQar8@0JNRiV8NvoL189BMJDfCkuuiO4YFj0kJLOCs3SJd13ZJbncthffEKZWOxz4YWtbV2YY6ka88fXrEh2xJ9u4jv/TDLbPbnv1Fs8pazbA5oNDr2MewQBkwlisNq0ZwUUb8zlCKPeMOdkzTDk9lq7RrWp61pSNDPBXU0Gegs4@Jtvh7eHMCnYbReSKrweUnxKOJSsuFtRCjoTML998@b1i3CHW6GLF74obj5DwvvnuDd80bJQ@jOfVIVg5u4@yOv8YAIs6LoaSIHHGb1gQgWB1Yk5U5y202Fk1w/qcjpCWzyozN6jwzzeF4WpZtU0VLd47Hwi2dgJJNIGawmbhvKqifT@fDG5OxTU7QJ6V1@eHi82BML78PlvOUzmwWCIWyUw4qMme0UFkXzNR624MZbg4IPG068VA3NTx7Gsc7y5TX7hRhtpprg5HjxHvX4dOVNim6XxGarYaw3PzvGC65yuTDkPbQKkrJdXm89YR4Uja24eD0iJ4MSEstzkWrppsM2/aNrBN9dQfZDyGMB6wKyZDlz@2rICuWcNbxV0qMnlHKcBf2KSCpwEc3WMsodJX@F0tEvwht2ZSS9x@nEHA8@Z1HXBctoyES@XNwQyHCFzOS3AdFfrncya1O0m@zZnAxtjkt6SyoBs2R2Y1KucijpVOqkuZSdBUoOTQJIySUsChQeTN7bnkt/pPG/SIEu0OUC4nFd9r9soiv7U7YzIjlkx4RjzQEL5Tv84RYNCMU8NKn0kbKJrWZlC9U2vUSQFStmAUCYLBpYX0qYXFLCBId0KfcmTiotRBfC3VEKqak9epFzffIYzfNTx25OO2pmijK9jI@pZSY5BltTOg221d08d7O3vuKixxk3kUaiUVtijUMxSMWqOXrJ5GPDBZPy0yYn6azj3tMO5GgV/N0D9wcgC4q/hXE2AUDRwWaqz8@NzVYfDe2gGJXOcbcig6xabNhTbg0l/fHY@PafhnQKnV4QpcFvNi3hJcDvSLbIShcPW04He4jAsJPKVTe1WIaBCKURlKr45BmJxHVrz2blgS5n9E4YOViZt0kFATtgmcScYIMuzJvEtoTvaT4OAm/SWXVOZTLhieCgVi5HknPq6CdzYsSPuusQuSSSXROQbARGeYQZP0cc4ogG1rDoeqHPvXBMLDhU8@m@FpR3T2@i7WYbROmJo2Tkw5YaVza8SVpuPU@6nyIKTEVRuvFF53eAFgUHeg928xnPcAaP5HQEzm4MG4wUUgaNV4ADyMokAUvkoxmZ8LYOlF1MkvsbBeoxWJ4FKgC6mSDyVoNLuUARrPTQa7QFwZxyQBD80QRC0ztfYkYNpEyGctFhVuKBMRRJnmkwzw3@yMTT0Ns0QMB8b@mOlwaY3atkuthDe7RG7BtJ4q0NwDyJ3Knis2emVcLp9JKkNq3gYwqpUCBhwhk6qi8eCPYk4SadoqcXLioy2JBo48lpyNMKW07BAaQolgBZcUF41ASyAIghxcXiyWKC8El3QXDyoNfkJ3sYaqqu1Gg1oLh7UWh8RrIU4rC5oLgwa2ddoo3T73jC0K5nFg5dN4GNtdBapzrTTnoz5pNFOK2ANjWF52IyWQB97T7zxbRUwWvSpCPXBSXvjlnjE1mkg4N/8umF9qIBmte0qCNkAIe4WFi/lxRDm6yibfQsYc8M8OvAc4hrfxy3QOkHYw6DYA5NURDMZItDoU0yzYnbXcKnpWFXJGEml1dIZfJ0j91tfOmNxhyO/p/Pp7DzN1ao6uyi0SSeLfLS@rvuiOB40PRX7U5XKE47BULk4ikHSgh8Hx2RsUvGKI98dtPmyM4@4qlpYq0M6CuD0sBPCga8p0bbogoCmcXE98EEligOrkFOLGmXj0EJVFMfKpXFogS2Ko3D5epA8FdeWty6NgwXBOBylS@PAGRjt0/TSGSCY8@903FRz@gPNoiS1lT9yp4bB2XK@HYXbokVVhfaChMGBn4a@xdVDGHN7rnctMehS/YFCR7Q/Mh6vpA04imnnLvMFcwVLZiPrhYVbSuUbWGvlVdU1f3wMB0HxpGvWd8ziD4nooUsSQUj3HijEFNtPRyAi4WgWRfrQDAjhhPo3m6ia1WzSzdD@wd43D7buNx9s3Uchaon3KLy@QW0ZUtcpF1cxnj3ftjRJp6imUNUCm5GifdjKo/oJmh06RShyLJZaOrPg5mlmoJBSje6Liv3OqboHWRS0PoITIYvmbgaGJ0N1MJt6uvAinQ0g7RNMt0rktQ2oCcHwPJGaEIyVnLKELS7/uM8aKo/7j8cMeKTqbJPpN@z6PkbDJaugUoUXj8fvdUZHqEtSME5LeRRRBR9lN3JOhSoXcoMeYLAG8LelkrqjneKK/Vqr20aXt5MTcnzb87qt3tFxqzh8Okyd@DVxT5NZPvHRyWUKlal2D3cOHjb3MU7Xzl2ynMCfKuUd7t7f2Xt0iDkPIeu6JO8cHOwdNElB/eDR/iF6DA0lpW1AwRKASYID9GDvna13LRj@npZKskGID/Im/BFXPnnlDZtT@j0jM488q0I0KQgPmalgUUrLq7HX6wwmOngb@p/QB3weLU/wUQZo6ajG5JAmg9efkhf4Op1bUFSP0WQ4JlDSgM@EeiLrlmCYnv8EC5AvIh/4dtKmL/KNMuahId9gmAmVRQMZLJYS@64Tn1YHLpOHs347o9GJI8/8WacPkPjatDwZnxRuLc@z6FVySEpD4cLLJTg5SuQcdTm@pPSgaKWnrCBG9rVrNaUN3gGKLEpoEALLFCrAL4hVlct52bOUHSBKsmBX5fhRZ8qyoXdhJH7NFWuM2K0p6/kCfZwg5pNY4Jg5wl/37UcpmmDyPkXGHHW0PDd9Rn91Y/mGOWNGJ0PvU4FddxG1R@5ChbfGGXb0Qj77gnknz11SgSZmhEfczQP08jYmDSaCPMf9cRU6ajyaKbYg9Memu6DlDfw9FdeubVSgycCEy9qw6TTnsjtKNBLyxwxAYl56I70WuLFhswSjOMwQ6zZEJQ7iAxtiNQ7ihQ1xPQ7is48ZxDvJ5HJ68DbU6s2brM3sjGdM8f8wxQsFDbuuVaGDwoDPLq5PY0aywzgEOldDc1D7zAbkds3eXlgzF/Vn/wm4bVxSqkBEuOILqr0A8@d/mF7jG7pL9NLfcQutDQqZE3nyYhNmvC@8K1NcV0lsScPYfrEAWzqtRzG@7A@DGfFBwqT57JcOTPy0@USPuzL9p1@4rgRlK4FVQxjBf0UR1F4GQZPL6/VF3kbZgBezV9cMFt2CAAGDXLdBVsMgcSTPF5Is2/gqsSQrNkj5MiQ/@5XQlPMrBuInBoL2WunMWND/cRYaqeZDoThQnyHRpmY/ePVNBH/i1sEuFge@H2CnIo3F9f78u@F6ByVj4f8odnJSAXt@6WGP7fh/uiyO64k4PmQUhUJivy0zRC6XCPHZz4J6cPeGl9miRfL5n1xcupxc@g@C0sExv6EPbuYaNLLwFmjUg9xMKlo32Hj8oANMSkxtrGPUrDlryeFZLAZjbgMqJlssztzsVZ09i82@brJDyOfMYGkuCf3rEWO0zhEGiTUKPpOVLzNcOnOjZnNtWW6Qze0ysy4G5tA3hscRUxyL6dkICRwrjpARRS25WWH25inigquxwo/fGrWe9lsYoNUf9IsSAcQblHZ6g2ceHlSjErq5KD7zk6ShL8JaEwKS42oovm6hQgVUVZyKsO43y@0I2Gq3J71JF9/QaiJXoWOkUgldxpEg2J/0fMGJJ@6dideFFtSQUwtYRBDzhlBLOoWBlb4U@RDpOLJRkqUS640XyQ0dJVHd2iNvOCZitagsgC6fiEEFEt66BatZeDRQPyNE7Iq2Ju151@t3MhY8RnH18lYC@UXI1bhUlWZGuE8sHHnUAHkw6TkYzmTESTemxjlFHy1@MuX8KvZcB@eNGnUwQoixjvB8tSo@6Mi1DCIRC6KRi2U1fyPLvUSI9mF69lyIG/nVMhIaYha5KCLP0EazvHVCbovIqJVwEDYDTaMAHGGAXvp1owytgwxTr1r6Nz/9@B/S2bNSSadRTB2v3wKZgSKSBFjx6@FgX3@30KN8IraKIdz/GOBm1MedttdrYYSasYUaJlcCZhhAxHwGEw2dVg26sN8MnmQsXzCaIE6sUmlre1sdvnOw9z5aQ/ElAs2CUHGcBGsqneNup5JOvigGI4jMhCjMfSGMQLoSUSjTKgQzLSb3OicZSwMLeut7f0a9RXf5A9R053UZQojZaXbqg/eEqFtrozUDoWcwjsP3/pQxD4asPRuPeDBMy8SEj8MOTH59FZmJtIsh4un9@kd/SeTEogR4PrxX6dmkk5h@yq3LhSzN2UKlkdgqhwx1QiLiC7vo@z8nZD4H6dYbYeqKvSsaJPHN/snfKsKBjw8welZJ5eDJXYjoE0ZkXg@o5xLxFS7E9wPGd@zRK4CN6GjmNvE@nJPFERoNZazk0gXd9@sfSY0B3hvjm8kCGitOdVOxg/Hv9shSWRmOpPG18CeO8I9tpGLmmoSRD6pYPB//KlimdjPZdTLP7yvW6gxVLbbBH/933OwjHXNYPegBnNHaQxW7VhLq/Nd/Y/BPU1emF0yY3/z0058FbZwmtmya2J5Pg9U0jbZimlT3K6Et6ffxyEjnpolD8UuXjLNypzXraxKCXyT1@9Tt7GnSkoepbxb99IJln4TkE43ELPjphUs@CdcPNK7YxR5uVsJynyYuc409YaGH8K8kVBMW47/Zi3G6aOQT13zytPh7Qo4MHxqPRoalVBIOp0ys7bqq0F/0zIt/N8K1sXc/vGoLGJcacFSADqUmZ@4h1HTdXvln4Zjyc@ZrgtSKOFvQLbKoVIQKiCatrh9DqlZ7bbRWsetA3IuhsvFqRFLzUqnfYaP7yfAYpQ56v@uR5DGi5z8MHhC/M36XxhK4bRBX2NqG3BPUqcoNesHxI9MH0ZHPIS1qoAfoYxA36O@6aW6hwikkb1wJY@kOmCW6QtfpKAolCiIiSeQqjVihguXU2IXwL2YHYunqiKUr7CxpI/mRDXIu3Ly//zOzI5leGrjYQyhzF@P8ZxkGUjGit3Ly2CE8XTLqmvPNCFJuqj4CEo/uf7V3ixC5ZF7SAkvC/MM/Nwddx0dd1mNoD5q8ksd/DI6JHZN4Alr7J38kBJnsSrBlJFL@Cz3wPu9QScTxJLsEnQQyP//jNE7t@E7i7OrFQpZgTJSx1O4D9ejhzoHae3S4/@gQL2Rsx4hGBk8W9Fjs5n2ZBFj3kiAiy1ZBzF9lcdbK4@nl5b3capaa/1efYvMZba6WLqetblpY7sdOuYout6CPaCgu3UPSP5HyfGkBtWPa0tpa7Zb0EAjQu/0xrle/Ax8EjC8m2OGznG08/dlk2pa6hTDjucTQv85mWZcxyZcJeNThANQqCsevVn4zM76cmUFXVjN8vavFveYxfmiFdvlJoF/2DHJuNuMvfE9PT4snGJ5qMvKKHR/dE/noGK40fALMQn9Al5roNhsmntcG2RadF07az4NPhXar/6Llo4LM7SmqRNe@8bUZ/00l3REPn/Q4FMer3hMrRbe9@Vm@nQdk@aP28/zJ6XFVMtgw2CiccCJyPyP9pefrT97wxEAMxnjPbrKOus/bgy5xu@mjLhxk6YA0t1BDzvRX@T702DBGXyLPxPupIqY5w4oUCh8NKAc@AlelrYu9aX3WcIpPTXFHm8XniJgLkbJCMOazHgeFDZhy/jQgqsnWp@Is3piQ4esDKoVoSEQz0zCORTjmTFkpfgNfqDANIWdOGlr@tGtUWvc3f4NxrOmJAXNiCB3eyZTqHzyuP270/c7pSiNXepJHR0cIfSRmjdSn5LOHP2Pvd190hwPfSep3/DEruJR1UvupzAaeK6z4In0V0riBahmFGy/oNNQOrFEmbtFb44wnZqqkjfOUnrfT9XTQx1yxulQGe9rTSgaShg9Plqm9jahhIcJ00yQdiS9OFyr9/gj9aWnYAvQ5OoDpz9CMEAM1uEtFYpiquVsrfC3jBOh29oEbaorOh6Goh7KsZs5l/O3qX33p6p/AuoivPU1Y3hRDSmPTDmy4HVku7BFzo2aNK9SgtNLqosu/9E6f3NNoxcFsdaWkTVOYDjZBgs5ag98WxxP8ktoXLRSkNUPZV81qvCx5XeguNZomwSs85euJIOV5A@EIIjHFOlJsahcDSZc3DnoWiyt2alVySpWcchGGniZUsiHFMJCn7bahgU7bWnAeAb4Ka/SSWKj81guMT8WuiFZKhmaw59As0BaGMKA4z9qNWOp1q9LWphVCgBMxguC4c9KadMdrqfCGVymYb2aP4q7UexR/k2nAewVMMNqCq6xUljGTTF4s8CrdI7eX8KmeSlfy5XyF/pX5fzqvE/X/SjSx7EJW3MRyPvTvd5LYwJ6NF4sq5Ru4Iaf@Fw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ                 #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ _ye{--}besizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]=x 3 8[]p#s4;93
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001332 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9575 bytes)

**Run the code snippet for a TIO link.**

Relevant code:

```
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
```

The key with this addition was the placement of SQL. SQLite already saw most of the `/*` style comments and followed a FORTRAN like path for most of the polyglot since both share `/*` as a block comment but not `//` as a line comment. However, experiment showed that SQLite and FORTRAN naturally diverged as some point after FORTRAN’s code and eventually traveled into C/C++’s code space. This space was relatively isolated from the other `/*` family languages, and it was easy enough to isolate SQLite from the C’s with a `#if 0` preprocessor directive.

SQLite just needed a trailing `;` on the line preceding it’s select statement to inform that the last wonky looking statement was over, and it could attempt another, syntactically correct statement. S.I.L.O.S. had a problem with a line containing only a `;`, but Alphuck anyways needed a preceding `p` to balance the `s` in select, so the line above `select 192;` became `p;`. After this, only incident had a complaint due to an extra token being created in the lower half, so a new token was added to the top for balance.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

## 199. [PicoLisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoLisp) 18.6, 9620 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJTFZmUiJLpQ8940Wv2@MHezw7GHvW7p7xLnYeDOxgsQ9reIAF1q/GwL/hm6fFYIH@B73nnIi88CJV1dfdXi9gSmTG5cSJiBMnTpw4ccmmYvd@85swftiRqY@7uukwR7Ud1ra0G9VKsY0xe6Zodj6bC4UQqmZ1h33VcOy1UJjJjGlGS2uDnznmtWpon1QLwrOMDSyzayl95vQUh6l2SxmoNjOHzmDoMLMzP1mOse2@eaUlMWVfM7oA5qjWwFIdil9h7MzQlX6zrUzF5KcyHFgQb7MtVf/c/@ywltnvK0bbBsgCY69My1YRvqXatonJVxkbbautKaRFAFUszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqAx0dcSUpu1YSsvRTANpkmEnB2cnR1MpZJm9Od3ZmQ7NspdJ02A7w9b1dFSOnVm2oivT@FdYbeiYe850eJ7VuqqhsGyqlMpORxbYhqXMJFlllqq0O5qupqBBWJL1VH2gWgxDWMe02B4USS9miplGzU@ZamHaoh85jbbE9FzOmapPNgOEN62eakAJM9ORshc5FZH1ItoaZaBYYxa1e6YFfGSxoa222a1ptYG5DH0cS0B6NvrEmoqtFlYQQc5DcG2YtwYwkWNC0zbHjsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZuD8XRoib3S9uexcy7DO8Km2YbWmIqT2ZECQZTNJOFz2cle0ILWhc7MrmwoWFtltqENBqrDI4FXVIuiITXTNeOad/Ajy2wPW9j5nJ4KeWOHRX6wQy1IVWUDISZS6GBh4iAOBiU4MftqsLw2M1RoIHugtrSO1uKMpY4c1bChyHaKaVCJW03XWVvVIYGPvZVgtonN6wc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjrcGA8SioBRRpJ1NkKlKPfYJ4vWez0aDPbK0P0U7L7HRUlX1SBz1IHmqbIQaf1mCqWp5vSQUYQ3VJow5AICBpTKQ00Mml0K2lAGktW9DA0fpAWM2J2ExVbA0FKiSxVaNNVB14otZkygTLsxsNOjxUfWgRblu1qMsRXuielgooFa@Zo7eW5jjUa1iNHamKxU4tVY1Nit2JLCEzE3NwsCIpatT19cj24U4EGpenSCkDaEwrd/r6RUhhqQpbapThW5Gkcmj7YIvdLV2im0tZYICBFVVirPIDs9OXlyp8R3Iz3bXuQ4A1BFTRWdocOGklOYACJh0oYFpBJ7qSN9nUQA9kzNan2iLAchyqDa0Bwoe9SVDNWkPLwpHEJ6pyDZXWTaML9ITKWkMD6WGwQgaaoGXCQJBg6g1QDSQvtRHIBaTwaU@DRrOxSQIdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1THxIcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9oZ1FE3HJBCPqHipLdUe6g6mGRptbHkY79R2irnFoA5rAR/fQHYKIKUAYP1@oF9SoQAYGsKkqmLUj//0z9vdLuCptVog2wS7vmFts0Ujt0KFheGQIcOCQNWpWACXwNx5csjgRtG1NgkIxRiLLKgQlOutOdTbzIQMrVsNemlPuYGeDZ2r5aicyflgn2B95ZpLE41zLlS8rzShYSkDypuqnWTPNqGVWmooTDyT7A@dTpElB9ssYqe/jz5diz5dvFShcLFUbHkpne6WgeFSyxQEvshjnPOmNiEpbUexTa0dGoydnmlkWbLFpFbFHKhGNDKBI5KIWM1ILIVSLhora5VWqqMZ7WhkHXixChlHYuVWpXWhrdXLU8mDWQKaW0SD3VWNtmJSCEQOdYqbdB@keQoGhzdJ4QrEmXYDSY7RqUAwEmY67IYHhEnZQb40kUFADqVsXVUH0UxKjqGYQLi59caIeTWdwiEqvKbV45FwJB6sOmGAmk5UFDvrqWai2NIHPRy0gCiGPYCRwELebcFIjZLR1hzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEUnFI9/iIuiTvcpg@iYJSYPC70GRPVtuBjgxCAPqyY89IY928hQypTDjMgOgwMFOlC00DiXlFarwiPCcKmawSVzQAW1NlxWRTg06A3Q1kuuD5QN0APJflMICNd5KA7OkrY8DS4sOq32GY1oG@1AfxANpQS0WZA8JH5QMKZjKk/meDjo3adiaZzecn@9hMF3OsdC35HoT0p/SjPQkrH@xMKGhYR71lumJ0h0pX5ZoYU1otdeAIQQU1sR0QRdPjDQUmxeCZsnuhpWfTedMg4qoWfh4o5HnriaFQQekiFP0kqDMqU8RUBTRHC8SSPp7OHQBupjKXPiDIRAE@SA8UwdUAgMnUkdoaOiDVgIFve1qrBzyLpTO4XOSD0HT2EBTMHSR7suNljYWRq0@yoVTaC8JiPIgiiS06iwcGV0RVnQigxg8GPI5ZsftzEJteEWEgCISm0koKeO8LOPumYc5BCoT00CLIZAxvB9DETlChhIHLVbuos3paptdE0GY4EWgj//UcZ2CvwTihOb1hMwWckj61xnvOoYHMknasseaY3N3UzSaIZRv6Z9rNId0aNrXRVIUozGvDKzt0AwpYx2YVGLk/DoHropGODQKTwjcROBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2bRPEOCJWTsdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKo8um2UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6T/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyNrkSpI9sXFp@BaR9dTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdlCJBLoy9oBQYVo/cX7iYR7E6NtsIR6VP2iCqXKyt5eoJ5UIWzyw@YyDqQLIBdBIfgCcSq1TQGYtJ1VuoaKrZmaz9Jkrnk5alDQQRXig3CvcLKuSIDFp/gNNISy3jIPs4TfoVC0ZBUFpbvagVubzIXNYv7y7b8cv7SAJTx8pKpQmVgvyi/VTXMocwXMYuVtaScj0Wu8jBINmsRDKR5Wi0mNQhIyUW@64Yiyuc2tGIClI7enkZAaIK@ly0ehbhGyWysZhHKigHDsygE0Yjqbsi5N@M1WPxCKSNRRIwxahEIkCZFhLBpkojZ04Q6PD4JSfMZjweIjY0rWv8zoh9CEvBBIsn3wH@3TyZnPb2r0G6spatoyqStLg2At70Mg9s08PTuNbYHmmsBgy3UAMYbdvezAhn48aQ9GdSbs1gRjQdRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOIO9oIJgjQ78euIoTjN@pCmzDhNHU1dU6qicSg4@C0V03N1YaO@LCSatk@D4DeA86BrrSgY0@iu5TYJSAEPk@n58fEyjOIp1UlmtV8qY4wsLQUA@nX1khrH2p2D8kLmhVOJawOUBVVdtANVKLaHmvBmN8FSqsjzeE6PPDRCSbZVexoDLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5doAaDg3WzDfUUFzwFg@eWTbxo1mmQYSObUNqIHhy9gGU8jnkRfYqFbby249TN95yIFiM8FygLZBrNPEbdktljZM3eyabBkAkDVTKc7YewaaSkDnc2B6yWztExGo1jWN8RQPqjjc26gjyoWcp30rCJkm@NQVyBo2v9I@wAN1Ptl7vw0jhJzPZKD8ri9DH6@SASzTdcTAFvMBhMlWR77BlnyvDnrjCYMS8gefRQI/mSrvmHxer8CACqUSPfwTJQ12ch4C/dyNaruueXXfJg0JTRnBWcZE7UEZhH4qqsO7DdQwPBWMoS4pJpDONLjfvjsgO097QzWktnomky5Bw8hWWbqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UiZcxLJkzIIcccglbXVnWtrzl7ZO7SDVRd/GHZjUWrnY/gSFOdkJhv@OIVTVK@rDW6HH57hAOSHVLpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHtpWWteawMFttdEHxVNXbYlNf8LsWAVkIv2na/3YNJ0Kb65rnX3xE8Y0bvL9rcb@3sZx7fgdLwShsbX@UFewKGtLUwCY/ISi3V4VsAN2LLPvaeS2aIilHJJenbD54/RUxK5g7FBY/APhBQzvoxU/1Qp1Wy2WNLnXCxSAqwiIln0aw7rxOEKSpd8LFJBFQonW/pTVdANLGOjZ@Scs4D66efEPJxKY7@TMPSK3jaE9CNTsTpYp/MbpdHDU9oKzFHydRFbX/eAcBfN1gkkLvSDLTNRcYA/fCuHj6wtz8c1EzQX28OU5PlyXmI9uKmYeqIesQMhwHWMurqmIOYAeplXCFFz78OOKFPfQwofIa270g4k83CXCjYsjPipaKhFBLmCWc0efL1zYDbSR@jySlSdiMYovd7BkGyYn6wiC/PIZF0IgCLQ4e9BOOSPHR5ELokiCzsGXQbx4zgiy3lAa0Cv90rohgSiW1EGAyQU/cd5LbE4lNTU/2APn7ZrVGyAChoEu7YYEo7xEvAnd9ZZgp8jyFrTMwTjQl@@ynPh9TYiTQO/KcXKTHELtyJqI5NQeuGsuE3G8W/J1lsYVN9Y1xDILtgsXhKcw9O6boDDtazatfgYlY8hT7C9Dkjs7mVDDJT8m61sJWfJmvnlTCiIimQ1i9drESbHvamRSch6xeCj61/psyg7olvQzATpTqNkYPlb0mx36mQOwJixnMCziUhBS5QVa/9G4Z4Kmr94SGNkACBlQSzOU9DE90BowrzyTdo2JwjTVzhCU4DRM0tD9BbBkqUiQnWZTewgU6IJFd59zK3k8hIlINrWSkt1ZD9oRYebDjRKne4cECP23N2MMYxNN4QwtB1KJ53/8WRuaZLbBesqYpgKeowGUJG7pPNh@Iil66Gd@WxPM1VDXFCIMub6EsqXg@oOie475qFGnYclkT7H6qHGL5gZ2xR/ob49wHi@5perDtuo@52dCJJ40ufHUhtanGsETp4w0QX4g@ZTBkKenSZduKm3CwqdGmkqJLGx93i7qiE8SAro3SKevKKdr12P@QprTGzpD/otrZ19qV22A3/lUWZtkskxeacpq2rSVpqY@wgeWcj1sm8nBdZcqjUUrzIH1699EM1SyoyvX3NlA53wC8CpaWrerWu7zIbDbHmj7NE1J39LjEVZxdS1G2rPyGE5L578Pgbi7VzzHw3TSdPr5FoYkFmlBr0HS4gJ5MkAmbYqwutIc43St9@2chRmSEguCp9KKxzM5HHW91RB/KX4weDg9DtWUvlSan5ovzXOSzJvEpPmSfJKbqqjOYpH@C70exjKtr@jJbDvgfFCsu2ZQ3zUHlObuyZau2MBMjmgO9Qaaj34eY3AcnlrIVr7rEfb2i@Muij20viJ6qejJLVPXbOzO@kNidNok7eeJmyPox0@KvlnCtkkvtntJzzVfEpgtBxc3HmC0r5BsfF0BV24CnJMyHyJay7zF74PaRs@8Ufnv/NHu09xSfYWMSurEElprTvJ260t8isvj9DOfitdzS@W09Lnhwog/OTP4Wk62Nd20YYqOv48RApRt2@a/83k4SDNNMZJkaw665ycThRqwlLCtPdCSit419UKxm1bg58HmHlodlPvi@bXyzpNXsvxleeWqRaYhi@eDgv46bV1/iRPIIG3hwlXA@cgoO09oiQWPhysI0wlcjZ5fuZ1MkVKm0txe8lADWK3erTJ2nz9hLHmIuu5YMhiTmg1aHyYoFcHhWFz1/im5rTyeW/vrBNIM2tUvVSLQuNe6CkMX/c40Kctm5G9MIWcyXy@eOvpQHapz1bvD5pWK@xEfmXx8faEyohpLwrKYBuKhXdGD@iQmkV9Vahy10feogFF0DTr5F3WbufJuAJr4AOfdR@A4Qsdswq4xHEw07sTkzTh@nHK9gduzzfZEITHmWyVS8csa1ISybqv0fUix3@6bMFU2@6A0GF/R/gIpGUH47wRiCvHVjAlbydzsvdVt0GRB8YAW1a7tJJrJv07oZB@a3xNwqQTzNUN1xvj7EKXnCdGmaerf0jIgS9sa7TvWk7jT9EstNKPkiI0OzLdk2GgVaXYesmHwcUZMLYF6OI12Hpk4By1Tj8wFZ6zsj4xWAZv7l2aXMFKTkci2Wq77IYYkW4icKqZWH2VHroOaTVVX@GNUWHkMXymVexSfp3UI5ZbWaHBdh6/k@Eth4SnRMxgDsbQ2zEx6al8l7yMqvdK@Gtru40GgkYnfOdGpNK1LPJBuoEFfN/B3YtUooA05pgFzKUexuipORnRczhShD8lXd7ljLnH3@kpX5ccSHhMdvk0Cd8DxKZzvnG@dWOObUlqQjK/ZP84K0HGu1bHtPucifDVuQXsO@182sk318RYaQ7/YqVPpuas8X1D3jJ7ZM3pqz6LO4fke6h7AkQ4/UPJYJaD8PcW@xi1/JI/8uVzPDlJXN3X9a6iL8pBLR9Ocb6fdxu36bUj6TXjHShMixOOLBjwYsolINHY/1Hd66hBGJtt0zIGaJN9DoDqaevjvfNPz3mHEZueaarX5fgW0@ymO1tRVdqtBEa7s4CL5fDNSUzcV3FX6iPIOlHGfX2OYapnWF60eXcV0BgN6NAb60KYfMvAmO/Mtl2tsh0r6NcygOXyrCGdZtWs2Wz3tS0VqqopjaNdp14LDvY/OS4UwppprLLmFwSldA1pZ4xQyQSUYf4KPvYfGv8CKztzabw4ta/xlwTC5AcAztPIFA3Q8lL9Yq50TTUM@7oVy9/w8smohlnYf5CZSoFFZTqoZ0ErkB@0/E9u@hPSiNcYHlJ6pelNhAstq32K4FHsDyISnBfY3QPg848VDgnBXyDeYFUZ3h1079mXG7bVBp8KfuQhrXTxhxReWbN28DZiZoesrhnjMHZW9RcjHVkTyjy6JpNJi6TOpDh@0benawOa/LNnJzsUyu5Y/CzWeP9MVzdNWO3yRAl1f0uz6poV730GFSLYs1W6hvRulL5eKXOQYZhekcFJnPrALO7cKs9sH5ukmkyNc8u2B2lVwL9y@htvidHt20APM0zsJvgbx66Fia6@HpqPOxTm9o@BrUL5Sulprd6IVXIQudcXGKf6Y6AQYNNsQtz3Npi3IrmN@x@FsRovzs5HTJnXvKNzjhpCAXiR2grLkHnN3jHoONOpjvDI3r0mtU6zLPyjoNIcMpuI5t57zd188ZkW4HfYHQ1s85ufexwMFQbtx/5rC7VsNpGDyIwhd1lN0Z75tOWA8BX1KjIS@8yEt@72mm132vphhoH6BgEOl@wHG2oBx@UhxoAcYc5iV8v/KVUu0TSS5UmN/BEZQcyypGZrzuB3GcRSYB7lPrBBXtfDATHoff1PPvhVD8nQ@VfYflfgwpI9bOsxsvgR19O4LEOrml4eWxxdd@AaPYzph6J1FsRNiCyWEaZY4CGen3NOmYdpuSidT3JMKLIznZYY4fDqmlWIEF40q8XgsFuKJcAGiawCYC0Xn/fAsED9KaDMopUOwWoddXLClu9FaZk2@ZxUmrUmsXudY8UMnU7ZHAzqsd8yTXywp9cpSJJmMLEUujTWWiXjgqg4dcS64MgHb0ejBy@uTgBkK31SMbrfGZX7Wye7ROUJQOtugvJ4ZZFNCRZif2OHHwU5xy8N/@Ku2OF4JM1wbtD4YDIEgeLrY7Ks98/Ypz1fkXhsMFDyeiThAbur8sFBys8agQ4OWy09VmrfsbOe0KM5qiaPM4DniWpBXCt64aGfBndYObzxeGm/XrMjYS@VWCthn2DdgXtF2enaKnWi0iXpo@bshwYVghmPh5KqdYHusreLCMu2NJ3uCbprXdMgFS/If/oqfUKMd8mLnsps9nUwN5Igb4WU6FtZqmUMotYvkk2qZAiSKRAYpOkRLHcOOReEx3DdOR@eAI5PuwTHKhp8e26ydsOQ2i@ApbTyPUtY60aXa8fM3F5l65QfWT6v/8Wfp2J0gnPRdslSwpQRzQcr3yFjB6DxE@7ERJi2NJJ6hd3xAE8cHbnl7AIkUzmR4gsDlMdMciF5Dh3/prKvHjeISiii6qZ3dE2R9OjdMDKve0gky2rZr4OiCB3INGzoYeGOEmve6ylJ0yA1KyROH5SFDPIWngIufNKYN9XgaCpMsjdhn1kMmS7Zwkzf4OCF1PIDXr2y4e49ywR1i6S21OaRNEDfZVDZXoeosNSrrVXJZatvEg7AX31@Ospnk5Wh1u562XaJeXo6@y2TfAtVNmOsuPUljz9s@2LpbSlUznz/byphJ0n2kzHe0gZhYujvaO9o@Oa2dnp1AK9y74mfHtPqKL2uQi2jbds/U6Ygx0MXSVPsb5I/nA/BolC0pbB0vz4jFQsEdyQQqaC0lpSXuDIimidRfSD4vva0G4mcBhEzraMzlqD0YKrANgdmQalj54QAPSjORVhz2JC7TUMZjB/IIg/sG58hSIpXEKkCsJBDrK0nFHq7sUx72NRT7IpbHyfZ0LghSzMvvwovnVZxLgvvfSb0HMFD@9vXmWB6vN8E8Um8A9ULdNDu1vf2z4@3JZMBj9CSpWynlxVZ8Lpyxp3FblHu6lU4tiYRojKtITKIE3CsGM7oZpak6typUSwjHVp8nJg6l8kshnzGBMhW8XqZe5rSIRqkEqIOUsVpTJwU62ihQRHeMDqC741X0hMCO5KF2C56SBOYwXfWRwo9bDcQqyOV2vSMS4kJeR@yg@pNwexxWDcdo0PMp1QNDlTfq2Az@A6OS68rW2YiJ4UyusyTLwldXYY7b82BjZT5GsSVOCGmJl13yyovXTECZ2lcKzYlpj5o4DAGjtK4M8Ey7gD6Aeega@zg06eSVK0w8/eIWZ1wKv1GFmralYG3oRJfh4Pl0d9wifHs7JxXUzrhqRvI9yHNDAwcqAArcb7I9gskUMFuHZD2/KYGT3BSH8t2hkoyktjiE62kJNrvRbDKiYiN0UMfRQVJibUTF8XIhOnPHaroNOkkbhm9@FQ8pJynaWc23VycNJoWBJ1OeyphgUghh7crsIW0YSm9bMKx@4ImXCI4w2wGckfXFZBIo19UM9zKcNbT1khFsjTnWEHckVCMzSdwirJEr2XP6egBwznUVl2r6x3/65/yKiksH3L8Q7lFmA3x/JHwdcP8TN0aWwffPPF8WfH/Mfd@nsclmz@WL7IUx9sFt6MCXz6SZOqFMcG8Eorp4rY0t/WbviNlkkMa27CujQDOhhEGe0wygl9YHprihNkZwnoPfhD6e6MUbYBHgK@APVG9Qo6H8VKsexdPZa@k0FhxnzSnau6yOuDWaDmt/HOIlJaCEpQv5woqchkImb1yEdGKyi5tlOcJYbA1kYuhGG1Q@NFt4KIJJdkvR1UqhzHkjvaR8n5M@eAVdAtgQnyhcMEiD5yi8FBBXFcmiS0pcjmFSHMgicgRlWtvkrAbaYJQcABLDYMM9cgbqpilIBXxsqCOHNKaxOwFq4mVUaEVT@VU1LqIkIOK48SqN6e7ob3/F8wOBDpoKNoN0jmAnCLYmzWPWi@/ZpXNp1MWVKgwY71dzWNcA9z@ec88K5yw8Qzp7wUd0@noOrA17dmKYuE16B0rLotl0NpeWC7EAh0oCFZQXu/pnQAmdG4RFS9WuzIFd29zee3F4dDJzUQVBRqbBIixSXY9fJlOJi7rniHjlniTqxk765NXGjkvKYKn8vQQI4W8omC7mvNymS/pA7ud83/Fs3hQxk5Gc@VrEtHqX3KH9NrPY/dh0AHCTb3ucyTUau7u/qK9XL43wTPaf513eE04tI3OB69Kmq3si08XEIu65u6lP8VJAO@Wes8lK/tVU3ukg7veDH75qwrti0L9vwt23HaKToN5B0FDqgR3dUPdUmmdFly3wgrnlBVnjFlXGovoZtkIz@0GCpWGiLrO3IYqjTh6RDrkNyb3LzuaQNglnbmWiS188mnlwpy5G7Pr@DRDi6oMelE7XmqFbcUrXPSjmndBN2QNdc6KxkCEgpo@MzULaj16k4IEplYsR884@2agzjlJkTYzSPUW39RC/h4K510XE6caJoyHQ7cgcMN@KtqW6rmPQqdjWELJo4YTsxbAPcB16HKs4WqigZSUhMdAz4hblAu9YEJRI9dv56CiW6qmjttaFEScaS4Bo@k6W/bsqFLxsAfSq5rwaoFlq0FOgDtg0uXW86mEUWy@R168gtzmy2/nBRj0EyDBpM7bGLReRM8O9Vggbfo1FEh5lmrFEJMX4TErcGERr2mSISrHNHu4AJNNHp6ORyhY8Ac4H845m9VNYKxhmOAs9x/2/Qa75pmtDApRRLpSUZrTVURRPaK/VkU4QHrk9v4nEpBkWp7tLxE0V7elLTFxZqDhCKPkXgEzJu1LJk3OToqFUSvXsEJ6ig0kJ5HjiWPvgBBUh2ukrAxYd0i0wNksx8kYvo0bCdqwYS1ZxuL5lBovHyaYBD4qAOQuCdsil0XH7KF6aFk1XoJEw1Dba@PikDdiFnErVwU2ZxNgS2jM3QZtCS2AsBHNUSLJGaEG/gL81LBG/4jIlrrpcomxDdBEDQM2NJjnV7ZF8AVpQrVn1iX/qPSBgOFVLpTXRGpPSvsSAL9bnCERAO0eKu3MEoK849QRUQxkNUJuW2tZAXj57qRqGCgQCnunjjZ7KEJjMiiXcy2YT/mVwlEOYF3FXHKOCgk5eErcdudNNUNeW0mUyjZXvQa35cIl6TUdoNuP0f5tOpct30SW9Mk6DrhmrRpd6FTmeW47Hl4zl6JKB2taTJ2hRu18CZa6RggnqCICSS3qsDPwMyl9lySgvKevRpXYlu0wpwAtT5DtI8IOdTt0tKffppSegLCUgxOJCJ7pk0/0tmVRKvofyYQ9ZSieAZ@7wIhK6QhazX9LicSxDaqmBBfghfXkSp2Hz8iRNxruymAuku33R3aZUMa8lZq6@5QQUwWvegJXHAUtsimu4wP4Vcbl5cQ@ofzzjl7h1mNGOB9UOTr6kyZivFyxCTqPMFUImyi/QAQKOokBE9CaUWAyEyW9@E5YLjElPC7moGX@az5TjkbwM03SYX4efgR6eXpYs6e5yK3nD1GTkoqPkUx/rR9dHR29jl1FWYpHw5qEkr0jfs1KWfd1nlWUf@LDf5hMOL6dD4fSy/GQ1nf7w4QPMOOBzUU1VQXzwT@wiGalfRFcZq66uLicKxeXEs0gjULBYNJuNnbA0u9Q0bWC32/A1e3TfczTMP0@fUl4w/Yd/xsNE/sLhehBEhIa/FU7Jh9nlqqIsx1eyz4wyFK2EnxyTwYm/RfjKLJ9n2/j52//9b//sb/@E/v6Mvv9eYdfsE3yuOwz/yf2pHXAr6G52PuH9NjC1qJBcGEQi@Vzk5PsI@8/2WWRy9enqf/qTw49hJ1zNps8teDrhj@FCMcyd4ABfzvXdhKvhdQQr3IfH6UqlAs7V//S/QvrqC8CDMeN1@KnmXVyFcbiarFCSz@FqARxyNgv5/t8/@1koXB2FP4VlWQ6P6a8Rzsj4KT6RnzAGjrS0WpRM85lb3lHg44alZTl76bdnoLmxab3gHuQD7crM8CQouT2uYoIbyPEtcHijcWHx2YctxlQYavGztvZshuD7U/7jVBI@KdENRuhJjtwqhIuVRINn7/FqOOCYqrD3y0TdPf83woXC7rWcyQulU5@g@mVYLq4cPht99Yf5hXaJGPZp52XOpsNcqnse5nZ69i1wofAPlcqxg3@vmvh3dIJ/bPRTPoD6KXwW4Y/@4eN58XeRQkQwgcx@Fn@L7hoKX4Qv6vXXPfqz8G/XwL/mR/zb/4R/rx38O23h3/Fr/Dt9j39spjKh8Pr6ejgePwbVUPDs13zO4JtKNYTP5V1E9zv9sJXDwuGzEAsn6/Hk/f1F6vtRvFwW/6A0lT0ffrgLilW/TybXv6/G4xdUvIuqKOd6sl6FsvIi08/364A4vn6xvp5qVKvVZP376sX6ZCKR7tmzOPbTZ5CwWr@4CIXvsC0q@LOMPy0bf7OSlCYvDhYwOpfAxchJDxHA6EZ@9IfCH9Y/RONP408zeuYmI1/L16/MQ///8HAEEdooc2VamV6mJ7dBIrKMepYZZ8ajTN88lNvgVOEv0wenlumMMt2MkTFkeTyaQPXwf//QdF4dmoDNhJTOKOMg4kwHnt3Dw1eArwN5X8GflslkRlDIUeYG/jM6Cmq67Iue3zdil6ELJn1QYfRPyZFUJpIqRCJaPV8YfLy8u88WPkqJSOPyIlIvh9P25WWaa0csu1Kmq97u7xuN7YOtRiONfLS@FH8WTz6DT6UaXxePp@Fq@enlWhLbj/NfqhFOrz@9rOaS6C7EoZGyELaejn/jx0cJz@riZQgmfOfn@D2/vbnlLnKQ6/L83IvFnzQGkYuC4AOg6bnpJxwMNM3f03/78L@s/1dnLHpRjzEWvbtfj9Inhn@x2N393b34rcaiUeGJrsMfBoAfk9zdV9FJQHfguojG6rH7ex4Gv9HYOkdYxTzWq5TYB4QOG@a5XkbKoOFVlqJiUe3ycpTJxMpNCPHM68pnWp@JlWnnylIT19RgNiAvxwgkv1Iurwj3arFcLgq3XCiUy8seVAY8wglAqq20ysjo5XAMi8C5P5pBmwpdpxmJttUO3qv@dDCAiZ1cynz@7AU1Gm3NajQwPPf58yV0pAjuW6mU8hCSKX7@DH0wEoNJ34EpVkxLMIWT01l0yuDMr68XVqrVwgq4C8VYrCwt8c0s0W68JMful9ISLx1MsyJhESUXV2MUeh/BeBZeZ0@rwLg2ftjdfZiIyFbysWhzrMa8ALlU4iFspRAtxkvir7IYY@vp6jITfxcXufjK8urys3rdH5aw95fvlIp8X7lT1nDuf19uiUsqcf@h8uRJrgT1LWbKl6FGY6t2Wmvgbf@SRKKVYSDJkRCuGQ6syAUZavKl@gXWpH4ZiayVn/H2KuZZOFIWcMkISCRWLFGFwzAb1Dq48XhEWPl3TV7O5hbT@dF3he0MaM@fl/FzcXFRzBbjyyCxlkuler1OoZ8XKc1Ff9Sp0zVIleSFXMjXk6iWXI06y@EBk1dz4eXQgHYIrWZYGxdZLTR8LUJgT7FZE9fDbVXX3XtBb01Lb99qbRWwH@3XNrdPE9l1QJndqW0msidnG2EZvXnfT9E59B9v17YOzyDB0f527WT7@d6b7bMjCLdh8ANiwad/pKhDtaHeDoe36G@o9NnUbOXqShkMGgP4jDo//urnP/7qv/vxL/74x7/4@Y9/8We//uWf/Ry@fwXfP@bPP/63pTz@/vqX/@x//vFf/wUE/nv4/jv4/h@//uW/@Bn/kv9v4Pt/BsL@RnwDcPwLpARsf/TrX/7JX/76l//kX8L3X4nvv5z@/vin/xv//7/EHzr/4sc//Rv8EZ6f//GPf/gnP/7hH/z4h7/48Q//ISD/@7/@Ff7/yV///b/7Ff7/L//m7//6f/j7P/qfyPHn3PH//Kt/y3//7g9@/nd/@M//7g9@@cDvzx/9/eVXhP/y9xDy9eX8GjxfU69vDfnlTyrPb0MNPxdisD/7xz/@i38EnPun3Pffgw/@vahfeB4vJk5TtmTcD/wFY5/ToBRlnn32QAHl/4ihEMw@T2Kj0Iwb@utf/vO/xOAJ2H8UxJCRZ2GXENjL7RcA@6@9ggVhf/Hjr37241/@wx9/9ec//uqPUKAlV0qJWiIpf8G4A4D5r4BDwMLXwAGgvI7r3ItsMZQFx@I6GiNCcvzDByDpIrhAuV4O5XPgC8lVcsvohoQwV1nms@U42gDgOwqtlMCH5oE4jCBxHhWHqI04q1Qq8dCoAnEECl5MM2LVIk6IcD5QAbyYiKdJNIqga7LRBmGBlJX4MWssV0Y8YRwDqoSBYYEw6FiSs1K8WNmCDCujLYa4EHk89AGeHyrVYmVURXQ/UBEAR3wDsgSoCpZuVP0B/BXCCfCh0dYPUJRiJR6vFiGkQlWl3BINylPOU@Wo7nFG9cZwxtA69vQZY99JclHi8zIgJRPQ@Bv3oZ@SdeIpxF/Gl0V16N910ncZ00M7jYg@PIzHP8VgSi8AAG8yiXui4JtMYmmeQfSIo4pTtvCIcwxAubgw43gBNMrGQ3Fq3zh5IH8ow9d91qsBD6LD6iwtLYFrvSrlpENQ8Jl1vWY7ioVLBqTjrDGpUJIwGLeYqEtHNAVY3lqGXxn@txdpmygnx3JoKYJDeYS5eSTjOXPFDFPp3apRXZap5HGCC4X9cK520roP6IsrLBaK0kXXMZpHqoMBPF/Z3Q1zBLphQpIScqHEzadimvnOXFur/CCvrIbgSf4h3rEtbnuGZsD3LqWwdyFBq3fJdepp4AR1oxCqVsXaFZND1ZPtU0hwesjkbCbFQKG8W1nNruRX8tlcoZBfzcorhdJKIV/MgYQqZPLZrFxaWSkVS6v3UKBn0M8Ta8vN/Hr1H8x8/pt/MO8zPxQ/oepbNkqxo6PXyftQdZRMprNU5IqcXy2PK1AQCgpVSZPiuvP4LglaKDZP6JK2Sd3hjhwoWuguiay6AB8WWgixBQiCD2BGyz0Ty8l7h2WxroZvMOBra5KcB2aIhS6BGTi20GDiE8KWewLi5onMnfmC78yg8xSP5hxABtAOBtvHDYyOyU5NvlFuQ22F1sWhkmooRKsQF0DVegjvB7@oh9bTXux8TJs9/lavTcsEHfWnw2woxjWP2tLwHsCW40XtKnjfj93XnN4DEGeDPh5CUa3fG4btfhMKiEZIDrABP5ZumvMAVtnZ0QO1fOUd9cPlPDrrB@DHe893TwPP0@3a5m6owDYOD7amHnkBlGf72zunnneVx7pJ8x6Kd9v7@9Ne8cB5xiLLryYSICDhB58J@tAztfS9CyKnHh45MwnWOOFX2o86umnLkUhX7TPouDK@JKxr6gprqNk8WyrJIPcKGdz8HrZXyqWcHD@Oyqux1Uwp37IqG8Oi40hPFyWYQabXq8XQK9zQBYnoYIJmh3ZhVtLHi8Tx1LkTstQ2zFBuDTpz0cSX9gwH7MFAeGAQOi2t2wNxd2u6AKGmojD4fusH0qvBj/N4gMPzoLCZGH0OOC5haR2WCaXIMJUtFfPFUi5bTBRLxZU8TN7yCTmbkFeLq6VMQs7IRblQzJfkRHGllFsBwQix@dJqKAzCQ@uk0yD3ZUmip2a08LLPdbw11Uz1qqEwn9jDYItvowsrXsCwyKRc8TID6aQQblZlWmVRwvc9ZvBtioBQYS0W3tnZzOzsSNIGetAIt5mRpDZ68sVMZnVDklSK2QTZnZUkk6eBKABzuCeT2diUpCFHgAcUJamHnu0CKpmSpKFns7azg/lcoSeL6QHsmsdwj@56VgHMQE8uR1qqJH300AFcjWe0QiXdRg/miTE7PGYT4iTpuVueTAYwHHM4jmHXrWutJkl73FOrYcwLqnieF/Ulemr0kSQLPMCDktQFR9eC6bQkNcGJnChJLXC1xgqE9cGF5xkNR5GkMScQkkiSRgSttK4l0KhEOGazu7ur9Jy22uWfscWfLSgaxGij4fZO8/nzZrfbtMa17efHGPPixa5yNR5azW5TJGs24GNCGoi57o@nP1DGvUZD0efGvIQYYyqmMW6oWLaG8hHKJD5dzKTfeAExLyBm3soGxwafPoA28bPRh@eG0qQY90Mx9Bw1m1IZedQZD1S0k2CXoU0/5WBIX2lZZhldoIKzxUg0khhfyPXEpzLFsD5j0dhdpnyPIJ0ovcoBxWPsbnwxqmTqoHbLZTTgRBf7TyW5lJfWFpWn0RG6C9IaKN4rUmwNX4JhdiIskpSfDotSYVVaW4an9FTKgXMUzUQyjMFP7GK1/lRaRSTS06dJCUoCXgBRIKG0WkKEpVVQAMr3QA0HpGxz6KiNRjR6qyrXsRivEX9xDjs/P4/d8W1OGtXQKXeio8SowkvDtFj5ExR@GlNbhZFu2HJMi@PrQv0/Pc2sUSUh@6IEuafTsXWURig/4Ombm9Fo7BmaQ@d4PIGOJrr7WEi3tddCp6gF0kvlGB7qbeJ7WOjEKEwv@O0C9NYUFXTCUihUFSrRqTpyUrsq7ilpJZPnE5/19XOAw5OneCTwYNhnG@yWcsEDAu4e6UZlA1BmygaeglfRuzQKj0LVtuIoMDnauBuurQnY@3K3coEIPuPPelI6r55LdRbMN7@agVKdGa3s6vr6xec6aIZA0XFYqcjZYnkUpjMgqyvlKExEYhVb/cj1w886WvQWG5UM1xSX7GH/IrNYkBN3yUbyXldsZ0leza5dDJcuknJ9cTHzubsuva9KdcweFUj6C1odQeiXIcxtED5MhDvaB4hna0n@Ig@5WIilcKt6w@w06LJ@9iEwGvgJB2UY6XUV1B25lC0LkNBAcE5UYlF8Cw/fMxONRFazkUgsUgaoRQgmBozdEb9EgIsjT4B3YTQC5i1lId5SnSFoQNCn3GJ6JeB6c0EOhe9Dbc0esJVSKHwXur@7X6@6CsZLNh4r8aTrfcJYNw5TqDStkODayiK5kqnqM1ar1LrHtbIArW3SRCcdYpf8JFYyvfit6zDx9er3/HmJa3CQTYgTh5Yq0@vxarparV6GJEkKS64VPVrMw@wITQg/hOlWPbZ51xkadNJ@7RWSS1njKtNFPfbDgabfFXPJKuneUehs9@H4ehrX91LVNBGrdUir36GwYQon2l4d6BzQQfN5CadiKhuclL5f/b74/auzw7PDHfYss1ZcK3JK0HaEZ4mEHJEjQNlnoBdox9uh8OCzmZd/MF6Uw2uDSG4lkptQ7S4r4hxyFPkgeoGrDvCtX8A0qx4DV6WSfSoXsmugw4WreBoyuxqukkMurIbrYZ54BWLrfAtaVg5X0yJYXpVjYTvJfcDP@bANjV989eEzTI/F@0G1LLnSaVGipfv1e/iv3l/ADPKeJpL39I8/afi55wDwj@Cehz/8TwAuCOPH139IrvP/dfrZPOSFlgpA7fCHShUa9fvG941wKFyKVOPpCL7rWuyZEDMzVOGWDfpT7WX8@94PWLZte9nzgXd9meWrMmPqcjqdvoy9zoK2VyoVioVw6Dezn/QyzCKXF2oswi@n4cKWXvruHraJTLxoDCf/ywvJrZPDzZcwxwZpqxr4wkW2eXiQwih8J6B/Wqqlq4qlj8VLAccIhUL6dPMIXxt@tnVEac7pnByF0hxf5LK0114T7@RI3DA5lWPZTCafzqyk5TyTi2uZ1bVsgSkgbmw8Fy9cS5iUUbU2zcGY6@jRzRglXqghDMbtazBlstU19vxon1LQkfnlha3tV4fs8GD/XcoN5eGnu3sn7ORw5/S8drwN9Xi1fcKk2gnbO5HY@d7p7uHZKasdvGMQfVw7ON3bPkEE6RCKKtQZOME8hZmt22M7jQqFTVrzRLBttq5VZzJcsQZKGu9anAw28EUMKt5WPhk@NGDe2Q4q5Ce1BT4@M0SvtNtWCA/oaS22gNr4wrJq4S5WqZexV1l@@PZTxsovstbKQWSVtTIHRm59lekZ8cf0lX7umC0uLl4akifng9Xw5gPBINzaDWF@mfbeby9ECytsGWYB2ZWYH3NweLSQcX0L58enC7IXd7y1kPU8ezsLOc@zDb4Vz7dzvrWQ93wbtZcLBT/ZwebCqufb2t5cKHo@YNKFko/zYGtBzoRcYt2YWnuBXjYV3dnb32bLABQrT8Si1QUdU8FAiOjQsPltCTQBWl6@7ZkJUieb4ynotvolaBd8AmoB9ZELpGs9wZbNAfz01T4AQ7KQp@EpVreVEFjxXhIYPUJ3oQWs0AJWCOAX8JwuwrHFCsvGGEQvdPjKcpTfU5Vg0plNp/G@s9k6agVVYIYEXXRCpzIhhSreDRdauBcoox2yTHVoqymBgtLMJEuKxfAo18HZ/j7PbABZmFZUIkhGHmkOTnMA2KCK8ItVh1DeOLxZqC2QVgtCecD314XuJ1ozNN2aSAqo58JCCxBMUvdG0RMM1awELm0iXvTwLeIADNHgzoCLn2GLRltY167qtKhAMSTm9uEOryEujlbYZCvHGGZKlKJovvn882fm@i6dSa816TUiHLdAzovF8fGSVhA2hmEL7uFBgqCD0pRyATkmHofUUB2KC9RrAYgOX36u2i1lFTLKRNiTJ1SOdfCVIpQFpotTjiyJIIhAEIzIh8i8oi1ScWML6WXcksBf/oxExHGEX33YHHt3QoBknS7oVKt6vdBrzgUDZijlKYEsojptbGtw57IN8KN4BE5OsCZ0kwRzI@UCRuKMIsHUBOtA8JRMbWgGcK5q@TLRZQXojNT6B1u8hfgFKBTOA6jGIPfWqMFAWDzB7kuMvrDQtGCeVnahQB4SFPAtMk0UCcHhHk93vEXJlnl/QbbE1F@Tcm9nzeUjnhrYQXAakRXnK5xXRHUpsOoDzeAXyLD/VgA9Z0mOLB4XEB6XCbDtSbhkksPdu3z5hUpsT9di8ZtrgWL5wVpsf2U1frtawLDmswjUAkR8FPDGAZp@JlszOw8FjIWEgmrz01DAAOrzEvTxCQRfkR6GXD998tvTwyC9Nt2Vod9CC3KpwJNMeluT3vakF7svhCgMpgTZFfaZNdElF8CFZ5dZERxtLisnE3YmvWRwqDDVTdPxJDDPAXgORSUHQwacFcYoQVI2XtOu9PFVIRVW22nsHWyfTsYivpTdEAXv4YuzKY/YJJgoEMbbUfTEvBJFO0gErm9Gj3geCaJn4@T0eLv2KgHli7F1vwdM6wDwI3rCRA3u3Rwg1FBbMB63Eyx6UmPLMfYES5ZgwiaAnq/OQjdtFVA9mGN7OMhSVhkO4vkne1IYe2RoTlZSlEVj7PPlJQypmVUm9wefc/2csZprs3FuFZVdjsfTQYSUdwXMAe@aXNlASGBPBW/fmJvZVSbDVqwcc9QeaNyjjDWLn@p1j2MbDYvuCcuBSZMyu0zvXkfZIu6jgHFxUrV5XIuksRH5AEOxG0MYDudk1YqTfo7sSbGugsXL0la/tSxf0mgny5LkZVmnTGfL8Bth2IPpUmjqFC1d62EOnIGCB01F5OEAbSZHGGSFQtyWErjdKWriCxqc2BrdyoEypdHAy/gajait6h18gfPQasGQj@qyLcDwg7EpHkkdCR2TkYI8qD9NRrQ1PBiKdybCqDOFkN4jXaG75KKUYyjklcx21AGVKlAMNIfhi0yDGcIEe8IPzYoHtgIljq0JrXhHwf7gIruYuJCH4xjavcScYBDPs6Eem86J89hmThzeuzYviXuQeE7c1bA/rwQgGB6IEUcB58QY5uG8BPw@Gz@ifhEg4EWQwPV6NDa/6aFfTbZ44EIiov@pNVTF7Tp7hwEWBOVScGCgrcNbKjBtS8Nrr6cReYeRIWV0FAuci/bYKuZzkmK3NG0avYtJIKKDfXSzMxuttXqA9Ts5W4wlAggDGPHCvL6iP4STBZBCCecgCfN3ljPXyml7qJEFp/H66VN4rN9ow/TOT2AOHoHHWB8WG98FXsAbmbwYj5nndDkf3dos41A4WuGx@eWJu6segnYrIceCBP1ts09@a/bJQP7YJ39S1hV2MVmOejzgX4MAv45uB/9JGbmlnswt9k01DnKNql4/wL54x0ggG363wGS2HhohgTyecqtC6DHgK4UE4goi@gb5Qs0nTj7PS@2PP8sVlpS9NFzi@b2BzOqBwofwVoRGA68TbTToHrlGAy1LjYbEc6CBFwe84KArOhuPS4GW2jApNiolFSkhJZO1k829vaRmSAl@k3BFsh3TUht4HZSUwMXFikQCq4EwPVUfVCSx4UuxGaWWHs6jFsgDKvjlTAiI50LvmQ/eE/rl7FrBKplfUSVzKjP/7sKvyO2YcsNj2o/lZPFLwNyMNumeKrz4y1I1FDT8jmTxFmC80GHiHgE06Ysi8HxtsvTZeHsDLxI9Ghgm2hqvQaB3LVcYWfsk914TaeYaEtHb0dSDCHxO5dwnHdGbVBjdcdVWhZ5F5qGU5N9vKAqWEjUN8LuroPFrIfwBbfKuE1HehGubtNGMOVVUX7CYA6z8hYRXoUADHJkD@PWuQwG3dyEKuPFKFAxyRR248T4UTNERDnE1CrjochR4AntL/l2MfWWk9YdouAkeuBeanF8sHPKxJjTqU@Sk9OMURYiUjpfaRgXeWFxak6DqNl3EMn0ZC8LPu48lVg/NClm6PRiLGVAd5iGde8NLLPE7aKSAIoai2RalgbQJiUlcCaG08lodJp8B3nFFDKrPU2Emt3oiIqhJwkvvj1eB@1wqE9MLpAhMHnhh/ATcyhR8Yxkp97E1TwXxWywIxRW3OeXG7ZoPFjyIwVXUYqFHZlL/v5knBZvkv9Cp0v/3k6KZqc/veSrzyBTmm2crv8NpwX9V6P@rQv8TFPrfmTb/gEo@jXK2x0@p619Uw79d/SKZN4Zhw@reoOkt@1P0sN@RIrD6TXqAW@oL@TFd4Mvjs4smGxzWf@IoHfpN@rRdON8xa7XaaV@2jp/XurVe7fgd@Dcy@/Hzq5WNrduN5xvt2tZW90V380B9Xayt7A9evi2@e9759FEF7X338MX7T/qg1Qu9PR7cnqtHtzm1aNeGw497u2Nnd@Osv3mSf7d6m9nW850N9eOWbm@9On378vR5/iR@@/HF0YtP/UzfPupklFI/t/uq8GZzfG6E8jfaWXtnXzvsn7S3z7L9/S3t3U58M7N/UnotZ/a3b9/nNm/j@Ux6b/Dy8Pnx2VVz@71@vLf/rr350VQKH69vB3vpdqmzeXX8JnSYey3vfjw87G5nS89307dbnUE7k93VrfzV2@OjjbN3u72XynZ/J39Wens1Pir0Xr@@cQ7i3ZXzwvCVvRI3aq9fZ18az29uto9DTcU8tXLquflaHtzeHpml/qr68mC3239tyUb6MP8mftI/vd3a3tA/ro5yZ@/OX9@unLwbvnr94v1hRjs5aW4rhUGznT25Ol0Jtfq5vfjN2fZZUXnePn/dv9nbzb/bSr/qqQe19pF@/by7@948Odrfq@XsoSHvb97o7573rl5db23u6ebRtW7UVtJ5/bT97vAwdPZCa26pu2/tF7Wr3rt0fuN65V28PXh@evWpd/1i4@TssJgdHY0z5qZ93NztjLaOC9liuqV/PP7UMV/JZ6/jhZurF1ntXe2TE8p9GudL@/o7tW@8iLe670cf9XT8TJY33@99evfuZPfGataMs49vdo6vrFdt49A@zBy/ePmqqV8XnavBe@PkRG5lnqvXr@IZJTQ627WhjdRTJb962t9/PRhtmR@P997bhU/xm/PrnLp1ffym9vE407w1Bm8Na1/rb2bah0rtjelsD0fPW6Wbs@tdff/jof0u9Gpbzud3zI690XmzUnqbfh7vXD9/uyGfjDIHxnFnpWAdvHl9rmnbvbdnn45b@Z03g2LfMbqvP531t@Pb@6PeJ7WYaeon766N0Fn@5Pgoe2u81PrOzu7xq4JzmNl/c9TeHcu116p8a6xujvNbI6uQO996a7273jUG6Xfax@FRRr2Jt98NnJXXWrPTeqO1@i9DJy96ZwdHb2738gXred/QNo6KmYP93c2Dbnvl5Xjv1XB7v3nVfr73Vn07OC1cZ7c3zgtbb09yzun1S6fUuunnjorxU73vdM/ioRfD3nD16Nz6@Gb0fqXWb6q5Y/2dOV6V@5svBtnRm9r24afu9dHAPJB3suP02b55rWc@nd5@2rULtXG8ODpz@qZzKo/y8utQ7vbTwHkxePH65HDjxeH7F8qKpp0rVydv2pncWTGt9azcXqHwXN7e6fQ/9kuq/GnrVU7J9Xtxe/863d5sn705v9av@i/7V61QsWS3NvbeDxVzu5mVM@82Ott5dX9j/1RWz7ovT1a2DjJHb9tHZx9Hp@3Nt8OzN4daZvvqRWm/u/L2@E3p5er7U/tUOTffvrQOQqNizrTlQil/mzspFQ971knu/KrkvH95VdjQz5vyi71sX93RrLfFcfF68Kl32709UTPN7vOtj8pxZxsk6dlRRskPrw9GJ6Hcm9P@zepgI/7uuvXyrSHrxXNtNX368ap03eu9vN1qrZzXPn1U8s@v1NLJTrqp7@Sfx483Xx9ddbfOPxVX2pmN/TfK29F2z3kXer2rbV2Vzq8PR2P59c7JuF/LGHr@5uQ8f3Nqbpyc754Ue6@aVqe5e9UD2dAfn13dDm921dXe6Lb4snf1Rsnsvy1uGvbKUSb0Qt3rt49PX76txTtZteTcHL47GJwXz0f5V0XzvGQeFrWXtc7z0evDznZmdaCdn47OtnvpjU2tXwSZcqSfWZuHr3ffn78YZEJZo7DxadPMr36M34zeFc7TR/H94bvWabZ/blm7bzVr5@3N0duXJ7W9@F5z/PzoWjl8t50/OdjctF/Ed7SCOt7N3dq1zZzeMUN2f2N0MLIGpdz76/0ujARmu9R@fpo7N@xarXO7VzzZrtWe2829F8po9LyzCmMEfrbP35iV0G/4XWshfs0afyj8@oZQ3@42zRHIS358LERHgkJ0JCjEDwHRTmi@y/g36eXQaXA7Pb1vkxt4hk1Q1ljbROUhxfa8u0vx1QUJ1jchuYauljmgJ6IV2/7bOOHT4ZfsVXhAjd4Wpo4GuqnhW2Hwhnqck1oqPwUH6ksqdGiw/hjnm47a55v8NXyxi7hqlC615@/PoasOQwutFnPfqZaiizS9N6x9AAViYHSTdHNqlyWTrY6udG1w6G1yfQideDd7Yw66pqDxA7OQ9xuKnMmLramorlLhTvF9NAfPmW7yK/PdGYcCysSYrq5AIxVdX6HiK1lt7UbVx/QOBLWdCvEdn1@1CzIYhlu4J8PousepvaGgbqjW1AbQAU/orrSml5/hzSLPltNiiRWVoYZiNTUH3@rZ4K9OaPAc3T1vg8m9h3RsVCzQcsUINRu6KDUhzr6M0DeVCilGW8nxeIEjskfVEFVUd7fh8vKAUNK@K8Y9AczLg4dxa/3u7wr1BO62pk7gNYFWQ6AVLUjPrNl/Z9MmRw@oHOKL9dtv904b4kUZfIvhxJmaB3ZcBqhcdn2DMq9BoPyi5LPbMnGHARQfzY78nmGo6o3JeVmifY@4PRJaG2fY/m5Lems1Fh2xDWg3ysVKne8gzNDWPZfgXponnBOeBEr1xCfogthQ4fHAV6bjGzQ5yGx9EXHHUlUCoN2c7gmQqc1@v2Pee6BlmrpiXKOrzLfKwnzBagUai14BEKgHmrK8uoj9kzRHwHpDUm8brF9QyfKahQDEhli3mc8M7M603x7T8Bb2skb7GObhzbp03WxF/ehld8sNr1vMzYnDT2V1iJbEDu6sNa0xzwjNM9FyGUBwnw7JBNVwd6sGal3xqYHoaFNPoBTAt2U3CM@oq345E@zx0vKsFokdaAfQ/KLyzUAIdeEVq86zelgWAr1jwcpMJPWJ424hAmd6mTnmAIjQERwHwxjxCN@dOkMVvtPL4yLG6XSRqcM/exr0rPGNu9ihVDR7ogiJYTfGGfpU4bxCI2jV6zqYlc961FC4gxubUCNeZBrM8DGcafH4RDsFkF9oSDeZxYna0TmxIIa8GgnSC9oTDO2Jg9bgW3FZh@/g4rQOTZFoHTL6/NnrMOD1uPHIPQUILOG9QxgZnHMm78uCoGXX73ZCz00xPlE8qXo/u5eeDjDCBNy8HWgjVY@CwGzgC0AGDILElqXBgDsIwtu@BMHY2FR2Ia8WF6OQ6oLg0sU6e8Ki8vp6dDUZpaDvirGY1xlF8mwgeSAxCOlqlUWzy9Gcm3gFEwPK3CSClfkIshzBynJUdhFkBQI5Dxi4ikFIvmNFzrWTiIsBxB7e@iQMvkZkTu7L2bhcX18v4h7PQOBU4uz8oi/n4llIzFEvxCdjOFoeEQivT9YIkOeygXEkgGIlngMUPOv4ZISf61SEl2kwz5X63MHpd6a8uOc03MGHkuPbDFXrooj1RU7lm9IHDNwDxxKB@EapAb1Xyg/jLL2MbA46AnVJyK2n4qGpBH@vmBi0gH7lqVExcDiCIFAMEBFcPFqCXT021jW/fbBD4A4Z@HidE0xOsCJMQ0CigMQoQmIQIUQDrdto9QceHAzFxRjf8c0HMMrkAFec8fwAtBOq/W5OJMY4@XCFG/CJ9zrRGMLpG4UEjf29DXy82T7GHbN7B8@hCRewHgnm/7rVXOQYvSpuKgZ/14TmaFAEkG18QiPqyptqMn8MdPMX2FzkAn4aO09ItUMIxhML7ZD4QnMamimwcVK6fKQ6REd69ZEHUIyVYZ7BblWm6EiOMX9la5G/IYkOvVFqIhU4vISigEghpNnpce3gZOfw@BVR7qhR2z/arSFmmGC2FKvN6B0e2EEMQ9X5oOrRM4TDL0hoXiel6b5wgl7eTLD8ZXCceADYoJgGhU6XCOvLmX4GngfPS0ASxYMGpaLRVgdzcOPeVQ9MVMaeg5C3Ii@1GApFmeaNhDTgzY6ErhytoqQjWpqqbUQcYGx6p4licHmSdvFtwCyTXghHPRf1qC7xi8XfgJXL0mtxkY/s4QBXh9W2FCS/0mqpNh2796kPKFW9Q5kIyRIgFITMr70vP/jZFG/sFTjorYA06GY8vddXcyeVRdAeOe1@ko4bUJA4FldHunPVSlKLRM78Lb0TqqM2qTI@lBnP7YrndgW5cYHLrqYVMq1@cTWhiM0jj@aS54rrxq5mxtUTbys5tVwHOr3dw7tsyBbCpQ41GDYT3eRgjidk3RO3yZ64vdjvifOVu8eVMkHYSY1MDDj@@CkmzO02kC06Y9ugkys0@xpa2P7cY6i36KGRkh90cqcYBE@c0gB12oVzxSeeoXqQMxATSEM6LXMhsqvToOLhiwqELOmWJxbQNegUprAKaAZIC/9wmqgrqZKmLSaKgUAUq2IUttpuJydIfzCz2tMHuhAIQ/mBQ/9UAj/GxzMqopPeKFgh1Mghvs5KEVxXTSYhQYzbNUinAXGLdaDiac78ahRnqyEq5@pkGj8Bg6JOuGUuChD0M8x7INTNvDy33oF6uIfhMHEsULFMWZygcE/0nh2xnJzLBY7/Hp4fsELBPx2MN2KxlWzGP3KMd2OxQin0k@xkvj2B8yN2HNGgyFbIMzh1B11Q1XXoxPzR1nDox7LxafGIP8ZlT7la5jNYW4hjMTTYrI/vKm@q@E5uXK91mDySU6EFEIqngbe9u4M3AHaHiqUYjsrPWKIgFyu7mCElRB1WtWz@Jnh6FzpIfHxVNwwLlsoNwBDSNlu0SRJxUDpo6WGfdiMlUGG4US28BkBzxEH/BZI5gh24aKhyJnADXeFQdXmDk1CIBOrRaGThZKRhGanHTS/ClSV15XQ/Q6U83ZdpSHPfm4oFIPIKViEac3doQRB4Zpih@fiyeHmU2yU9YF/0zzMNzg4yfHLqzsMFGj7GzM78tfocYwxxVys4Bo3EJiZCRXWqx9wzcCQB3CNQLdcOwYHoMarT8ES4@GwUKYhvUte4LZyRjCAtgkYpGlIs5DrcpSOuSKPoBe/N0cTPFeh9MbEzYCwOzHnHIwUEsnyMQ4izkdMQ2D85xCiIA0rBO@py2t9/MEIc3nk3FN/EIe4sHN0xMS9ABHxeS2oXLz8/kza/FqKPUqb8SNp0SSkqFujL88F4lQUY1i4ABoUieeRWygU7O/LPvbmAVHoySD1W@IncvrbwIrsZoAlKfGXRPULcC1vdPKSQuG/eqHyRSmyrEWpmoH24kgSNKBiBeJb6vTBVCBq4UoGXrhlIwXVmN40rSShGHPqdFTkCynMsZ93jwK5A98yc/rneeRXlnOxW1a0mtSC9vVnXBjQ0TtZVdItgXZPybGVXA5V1TxlPVFYkcus5e7@DAY6Obt7y@xdwQJHEyWXpu3aCfdfGxRAREhyjXGrMk3@TZ50DHfL7it8jvfp5ZaVDs56H91WxdoiiPcjvmA7xZtxOjq/vpSFARnDTKLub63mqhQWhzoDSM5EuGxNmZ4@dXRSdDshr2qqPd6DuZ11MPscQlgr7geOhIeiTak0Au2CfSc5jAWIeLL7CPAgb4CIhmSc6qcsdGBGPi/GsMmEN9g9QP8iIQSxCdgaOKD@anmTKbCnGGMeHyfk43CRiuPf7fzlYkPGDBUFy0BqRGOu8NSN@JcL9b7sy6utuA6G5gd41yMLPR6GICf0tn3H1gOjA1xe82QGfDwR1A6Fou8ogGrZAgYe5MT8anWCQ@4Pw/g0jH/kCHx7Ng5R0A0gwGV01ERRIvITZwLRoEJjEzBaTWocoOuBtMlluakgyhHjYeTWeDC4QWTqbxGVA7ozLM7WaQMfokDNZ48r88g9SZfECa5qnBm//wIZfxsrjkqU/zxrg4WB3twOh0PoDXeUnd@T9Ru1wz7vaion3nau2iUF2yrS66VvtWktzwNCJuLYqqQ6xn@MlVTymsX0GQxleOOWk2InKNyug3otq2QeaTqrD2AdMhDdgGQDc6YDGa7RUfPeFc4v7BwQCOxUsLEQrNujhpsHGptn0S6@Ikzm8AAkquw2F7wJhhk16OXtLcWx1rKYxYbqpw09fwZuI0zAlT2MN04eGug@pT6BLqKkr5UYJbQUKRienp3Klq@ZCSbQdUYyDr3um3SNoQ3DoledNE9rG258qJgl0g6Jp6GNm4BUAXQXfO87oDbSQFXLeLVSTdtyKRR3a8qDSPGIlUyqQsLfFCEfpcPxOpSAuHwvxV5Wu4fkO20R2sVTam0rJJ/a0TO3J4B1zchMFn@dPhrXwcq4v79Pwtnik04G0pvE1@z7m7fGg@7@A7A/t/Ein0Tw60JUxk24VugOaba6sZgprONfSugaxIfYWvEQnoLGrowG@8BM3BuA47qbV1RtVZzlsxjeaPQTAE2cIVQqFB5bS7SsuYDS3xjCbwB1dNL@eONHvR5mmPhnSwXMTzJ9R48k0xmQfG53gEqMKElMEi3FBjYHUgp@nuOXZNAdsDRxttTns0mCA57LcFHg6Skk0MYESq0absafwXIMnFB2LtAz9GDt/xbu/CvcTmRq7gG5eZ@4ChVQOUS2g61d46ctuehw5ECywogMDNl/VgBFhmTXEZJRbCQAax7Aoh7O53ZMWz12Qtrl3iFYbypBvLnZjsIoDcaHjg3tKlllgTwmIBLxvChmTrsBKp13LSKSGr251PRsRHktWoyh3@yYiPuote@Rw9y90@O6TdboTjNFdnUTOWNndVS@X2b0LiHtAUMPBnSXJiLtzADVMC9dm/B0pQHrJnYU9hjZQgNwXIKnhkM1wXApUg2/wrnNrl1BBpqPluruGBeGVTNmlBn/Ts9f@/mLWE96aC1TxRXpv9B0T6rTU4gsxtEoiFpgmyoqDl@AR4g6OSwzxUc4PFDDJDcKaSEbThGdQ5QXlNlcQFqhzJmlISbAR66L1nU@fEmwsvHjNeYjfZJxJjCty2bv6WDWG/TucjCR4kuEggcD3TAVpXw7hr5jRWTxzr3fDKEFiHQV5iAQFBl244WjauMskmHxfppxb9CYoLuJBj5jl/bl7sS4NxLd2AVMR@q/zYWLtu7aU4PnhkgE5ZNeRrSf83DgRvVKPxuZ1dJQYg@hgeB6pKmYd6BbGefKOA1F0R4lYpxECBu2wDQXXHRtIu6h7AxlrjCowQWqMK2jD4/d/ocLLuwVdIIPwawwAk0kEhBkqc5Vdiicyg@gbxeMYD5O6yfjhYA1n2W76mXhsPcLP0wfx3/uX5BEdGqNEYxxz96VAisZ4mUjgbU@5n6kuFe@3qO9MeafqO0MPr74P0MOr7yw9f1J9PYvxW6oIDDH0wDkOTtmfwowa3xTvBnI7xVOGgRl/hNp6N516OMA31kylptcPzKY2BwPTxluZ55eA5zmnEBQfCIc8n/I81sANE@Q0Nx/JxQx0PbxS3g7xLm6ZqC9GyY2v6@PjF@iTOrdtizGaAhBziSz6njc55YcMYmIoCQa5ItGrH2bFZSpXJ0Btu6b9xRUWyKrsFZwqyudgjBJ7tY8x7g3gCFSdti9CadwkSKgYm5dkiHoHpptOgmHzkwiqC/k4mQqpzuamchsRU4vdla4mRGJH2uOzJF/rlgJrTQ2SzsCuAX3Cm8d69t5R3GVw3hhk6Y3E3VEapmJ7HbK2bfKN2OxIWKfw2BOo8E7PMofdHsOLolAHRFi@pbxjonaP2iVo9fgKyCHeVbPmbouL@tX37MdpdjZgMMmn8/PYc18dsU1U/JtjtCVzW0A0MEyIHVYLC67utOCbtBdI0nvAdW7o4xYHP3tqs0ABtpAfoAiv0BIH2R8TO83J2B3EkrKngUiK46j9gYOatcargNX3kw1wGcZPiBqAe8cXKSsLHuj8wnI2DpSWShcs7j6wyrzSZuYWko6hTheyqaKpL/NI4bgVcdp2A8XB3LE0W@rvof28XPnqNcz7v8CakKnLlQmCU2GSi5ujQdnBo3l9fPUo3qzBORVm4IDywLRwbjhOzMV8i/Y46l3KLcy9aKqMcPGUKE4P5rM3uNFobmpacesp0FR0dAARQQlIteJrZ7hehm8Hw9SvaDrqJeYTYJtUObx3lhfDbOEqs5t4lhKW2VLVto0qq4K8QuWM4vEG0V3dVcK2pnRxhggzdVf0usUhezTNFntai5/K2DzColjqx6Fm8ck2liYFbUn7foAVNntq65pg8c04PvakZiSBbIaTNDvM/jhULDQ5mBaLR@yQkPF8pDkWO3Gm9SghoMoTwMR5lVklJACM6ideBTnFVq69Dk01rsyjzTr4ooiILV4CIWxG9LrZgO0HrSYpBvLKM8jA8KyLE7qaTXgC0@8E6wx1lMXmIIVxKAknKxv0oWLZXKzwSwwnqhnwTABxwToZG8AotqFYHoYoDeNiJOaS5svgpRlozOoB4CSH9uZYAfp6RANSTtBtYnmHDgX59guIJvt5FPnNdmE6uNfCUsUUAtNkYgnKZBYtDcWzWA3TSAYxc7BZxACHYLGvbb/Kf6b2Y6gAGSh7QMDg8Xe0MLYUNFZS0cXsE3o61RIZWVQF5EB/qDuKoZpDWx//vhkhtEAvfRS6MwSNyftOeCfVcZyG8dlZGl8GwPbSh7TdDfcm4EQdhHd2fw1jpFMharDh@qYYZ5kujsHYCfcNMbhMFD3FuH0Rh4OjuydgKgavTEBLD24TcOiMV4JvGwDRScfFDCdF6dwNdkrLGZIQ7Zm4uQL3lA7RHoR7PCw8IkZNggIb64LIzYFq8cyA28bmkLnjM/Crf9UnCEj/rk0NMhVDH@FH2YzVQr7nAwngQdwBVLjlsKsG0oD4hYIDONmOoNzu8NZUhY0CBze@uoWvdMQcKFt4Im6Nn4HzM/zJufFVOLT5YpaIeypdBq8VgM4WsJLxffbRRTG/j7kT/an9T6Qyu7YuF5YzlNjbjysJtKti1iznTmC1Mm20iGoV3KmxjicsoF8C6IVWX6zgWgvftUG2M2zFW2AQVbFaPagStJeGDONYRKe21iaywRwOzd7eVeY2A/QVzJUr0Maw38QraTpEL@@YJq17oJEcQKI@6hjl7B@91EjCaXHg50vc6kn243bM61s8K5qX4OQHAD07Eo6gokxkvxSEQb@/s8mjTicqvGgKySJZ0H8hAvGaEnEf/UxUtu7eXO9N@bLlaYzyIxhjvvFs6kgYGrycwBanW9O65itHaHYjye8oGtm9cS2Qb1jGRK5FDxf5bT@Or2S4xjn/tSbUn3Fg6SnOl428Ljc5IBR1fqCHH5zyCczX8Mr@pmVvN3KG8xaIsBa3QKVFFO6M4mn5yiUX7B7zuGuu3IbIzwZlgke3BK0rwa7A21qYMvm5NkvvCO1qgjcEpOAIhHZLjuZ3YZJ080gSGoLihedzHCp8vOKClcVxp2Qw5B6n/7ycLvkEr6hGNeP2Rs4flQrnDj8Pb5NwK7BVd9k93sD3k02Qn96@WvFe4PDT6EYSg5tTy2wk9nfRSasR3@G1MDX/ZrzGF6iSLiyMv4U6RAtvm7hvk5eIm0U3oHmHtxkwy3ljapbnCsYO7/pzjqqITZ78dQcwvDN8mYI4vgHeoDHcdmLecr3ooLaTsh3incBIn@TSB/h7Xr9TdNsUV5nRwMoT2bRe@G0rMW4P5NmLftccdrAouNIPafwDKrOnUxY7nsihrbl8wZ9TisBp3@EQcfD@//@292zLbSTXPQtf0RpqFwPizotEERwuJZHaZSKJDEnt2gVxsbgMyJFAAMYMRGApbMW5p5JKleONHTu@VBLbSSWvScqOq5KHvK//wV/gP3DOpbunZzBDUrvrdSW1VIkEuk@fvp3uPqf7XHKGtqByqM9WKwBFJivyhV8WrKs7cUQv1ai78o6MeyAWG7Ja2Qflwgg7QQ/ehjsbkqreHrkn8OfAwxZ1/CzyS/rlu5TZ5svE/b3dJ0c7B42DnXd3Dg53qCQp8muD4vGwTDdl/jk69@5LvFk/4hAn897Ig3McTxyKs4QS@GF7EATiIYi7LojjL5pQsjl2M6lv7kuP0vOe@u5oncsfMTNPxvekaex7aCI0RlUl6N85C@D8PGz7OSZ@OAPJIRVqvfbQkwHHhcrgngmbOefg/okrqTWgILQEIS0b8EgZdINz5AClNBF9Y4aTpteB1eyWpI6tgsYrh9BfgnaIgAwA5KPW7bREoa7NtQoD7wLPiWwktpUD14Ls/aAi9rnabapWbHO/kIds9gb9k4z0nmC0gDg3OLQKGEh7XQ0xGQVBFai3gJ4CcaS5R9yhMsoH5WqpUv78XBqEj9i/JW8Fn8Ik/1Paec/b6SfGT0oy21cxAAweZxazoYuETUq0oEuO1hQ1qItVtCQr@nTm5OnW5BL98m/ZgjzFgFy2buWLMRr/fO25r21m/Zl9LHzxZjiJBByxylHkm6hiOvv8DHb@r1iNvJ65yFVWFF@aTiSbTsiAaq9jPJFdzJL2MXIeu3t8YY9XTfr6x1fa3TKcUYwnU7tWRNFWR7CJKs2H8WikJvL1lOgjGvQRtfLfmDp8el8TbAHC7iarHb9Grw3jiEhHK6@lCa8D9Vyh4m5q688i7Vf1mmr7qNI@miLvGV6k4ZqTzY2qSNNu8@qViKiBs6UL6/gS@UsNc23eopzKG5dxShldnh3qzoxLxtTf@VIwobQO8hbIGFkcXisaYk5Sq2mTKOEqtYhCvJSjcgrXbH78Ymrr4QiGl6XkRMy8xJdttRdxbDAQFZ0NaHuQi89RBGV4GZuGMjo1ai7SKpMLbc4mRL/A/3@xttIkyAYeXxpZ/RaNrL60GvnSauRLq5HLrEYWbpbH/qjc8vplYM16ongO3H9mARbU9p547517R@LonR3x8OmD3xVf3Xsq3rv3BFL2xP7T@492Hwj4v/PkcEdQAf3zrjtClXsBU7/ttl26nV@qVFYEYZ4LUL4iDptn4p1B230JxLPhN8@2TvlLqe8Gm1xq56U7mg74OWiIyiyBtJqguyJ@a1I3Tmhx3QJKPsN3ROXLE9tI3jx9vlki2wsKh64NuPltj3gQ0uOiZyVttAHwA0gFNE1@kiXdaXxaJ6alUxJy4PTPa48gMIWPD8W9J9sY6XN792h378mheLh3AF/3v4pudsT2LrqNuf8Uswjw8d727sPdB/cogRtQKQm8WyOD9cuaUEJwGpX2i@4Yw4P1UCqU3yJevRcymf5AWUX4Ijvuh@57OkBS@O7Ozk5r5KLdvnXv4O13katxvyYsC4NcGg7VpQXCrQoajUBtMop2jZ2pI2tZrPKGdDYVtzC7lqE7IPpcEAp5jt6JPVdYD/AaER@kKW42M2wKNVR0E3AjKuUI1hEUgSGbLWwQyk2ojW4PVG14sdpVX7DolnTMinLkgvLS6hNSDM64229zGF2VAHTPWt1UbTBiALwQkgkMgHcwmBA0X7i7eEkiViXEOEDBHxJuc8Lzs@HDc@Qa0cBVJtznQCBrsk08bzSlGOCo6fV5HiNmTbw7UIwUKuITPDrJ6fXUlSupxAH/L9/Y8FUWIC3YBbuwspVQET67ATXA3n7a7Aa@sJ0c3gaDCOL2PdbUOuk1Qdyje@ERGiy9RDUCqnbNwZ9N5aheMZwUiFOJMK2piLZDl9uWB7973XJQ8v5cjai3R51GhSkZ/@nKBtyfa8CnQQOIiuZ@gW6FhgExtoRm0JWkbPsDoEgQ@cRH0ahGg8647UYKSFnHfu59@GFODnIhLGKo@FDrtIYdhnrAh5Bz9EFFbi5AiCFNyVN8jeI5tKM9CN@Gz1AZYoQN/EANrqzNFB5UjVITR1aK/HxKra0mGcNdWStRPOsG6@1rqH1G0fO3z2Z59EzSQjFZS3M@@nNGJQb07DRCNy9dgYpF04BawsEdMuHe8ZHwy/X315zN7fvPih99UDgul094W2h2@PGClRL5mYVEclgeWneStAHVSpNIM/64haWVPiPvlrjKFTJgXE49YL63GjWdx9eq8@l9ipcVTafEV68cLlUkexMiIYwkE@5uBVFXVRaozLHISQTh3gmNRc@6KqVAOPV@vYVx7XEWajAifdxHSL3GDKtG@jWGt2t80IOdJSP5NJ5ujT@nYpFLiqIf25yP8vv2fSe/mSsrKFpMejhttUUXFOZqTvZqhtNL59Ucuu3L0cH@fX10a5e2jo@H18K2fSm212pbMZ@Oi48lA9f10X50CVo@3D4VWuh7IR0xH5Lz2DSla@Is3FpQNH9FjR/MzR2tPUCDZy9GVNVIjdrG/R56iLP5UhyaRgVyJpqQITo82t45OBDWDt6yrUNZ2Pea/TbZl@I2iLhvKk9HbIdMm11JM006TJBmnlTKjM1Lo9VetpgTBy9lq5A8SEGOh94sdNRekEwm0jqCTxZiIdDwmjdENXLR1l2oPcivS8SzOmpCiXDSjA5mEru5wIcPO9mnTSYctwLzxv4Lb6iZGXcinXXRVfVoaiJSjDAeB80TfPlOnr/3mD9eV/Uwg@V@bUwdRiX8NvrLF4dQ8RBfikvRGbxkWtSUks4KUemCGjsyy4ty2J@doHQs9pnkhY1tXTLHsmnMH98yItkRf7qF7/xTmdk@k/edaounlA1zQnPhoWdHjyBgMkEMFlsmVUDx45k8wmg09DnpaIbcXGu3qDV11UqKZiZx19KB3gAOfvV2fHuIVwW77aVVFT@fqviUiNRkxN2ar0FlAubbq6vLV@GO90IVL35W3HyGxPfP4Gz4smmg9Kc@qQoB5e4@Kaj8kAAuGToHpMCOrRZMrCCwOglnSqTvdBiZ7YO2nI/QFg8as/f0qID3RfFac2ISa1sydj6RTOwEMtcHYwnrjvKqmRv92eXV3aegblfUd/P16@PFhkB4Hz77NYfJPBgMcasERnzUYK@oIJKv@6gVF2AJDj6oPf0aMTC3VBzLOseb2@IXbrSR5hq3gsEL1OtXkTNlbDMLn6FKZ83hxSu84HpFV6achzYBsqxXEFvPWUeFI2tudQakRNDVoSy3uJXRNNjmXzbM4JvrqD5IeQxgPGA6egCzb2YFyD3reKugQk1m85wG/IlOKnIS0GqAsodOX@R0tEvwhr2pTi9zesfFwHM6dUNiOW/qiJfZTQkZj5CZtSQw3dV63WmDhl1nv8XZwMbopDdkY0C27A106k1ORZ0qlVSXZcdh0jEngSSlkxYkFB5MXmDSku@6Lxo0yTLaHCDMFkTf6x2XpP7UW7aUHXPShCPgiYTybr@ToUmhmKcalToSttC1rCSh@pZ3XCIFSrkBoUwWTiwvpC0vLGACQ7oR@pKJiotRA/C3bIRsqkm8WHN96zlS@Mj122NX7ExQxlexERVVkmOQBbHzZFvsPRQHe/s7UdTY4gbyKFRKKexRKGbZMOqOWrIFmPDBODhtcKL6Gs89dzlXoeDvGqg/GBlA/DWeqyogFMe4LMXFq84rUYfDe6gnxe7kjuWkqx7rPpTag3E/uHg1eUXTOwFOrwQk8JaYlfCS4K25YZErUXLYihzoLQ7DQiJf2VBuFcJaKIVqmUjfHANpcR1b87mZxJbR@ydMHaxM2qTDgJywTeJOMECWZ13Gt4ThaJ@GATfpLdsRth1vGB5KpdJccl7c0YEbXTPibrSya1aST6vkblgJU5jGU/IxjmhYW050BuKV90pVFh4qePSvxaUdPdrou1lOo3HE0LKLwFSOjWx@lTD63MlEP80tODmDIhpvVL5u8ILAIO/hbu4wjUfAiL7nwPTmoMB4Ac3B0SqIAPIymQOk8vMYG8mtDJdeQpHkFofrcb45KbWE6BKKJNcSNjo6FeFaj81GewDcGQckwQ8NEASN8zVx5oBs5ipOW6wiXlCSIokzDa7T5j@5hDrUNs0QQI/H6mP1mE1vRNYsdil8dETMFsjOGwOCexC5U8FjzUyvxtPNI0lsGsXjEEajYsCAM3ZSXT0X7EkkknSOllq8rMhoS0YDR15LHo2w5RwboERCKaDFKCivmhAWQBGEuDg8WQxQXolR0HwyqEH8BG9ijbXVWI0aNJ8MaqyPOazFJKxR0HwcdG5fo40yOvaaoV20L5@8XAofa6IzqnInbnsc8EmjnFbAGgpgeZiMloTueCde8JYIGS36VIL2INGurEmP2CoNBPzVO5r1oQKK1TabIKsNEeJuYfBSXkLFfB1lsm8hY66Zxwg8h7jG93EDtE4Q5jQI9sAkG6KYDCnQqFNMsWLm0HCpSSBqZIwkLLFwAV9nyP3WFy5Y3OHI71bBys0sblYtsotCn1SylI82NtRYlIJBwxOJPzXZeMIxGIoojlKYdMlPBMc40Kl4xVHoDdp82VlAXDUlrNUhHQVwetiJ4cDXlPm@qIKA5vjqduCDyjwObEJeXNYpE4cSquZxLF4bhxLY5nEUr98OkqeS@vLGtXGwIJiEo3xtHEiB82NqLVwAghn/tpJILTIeaBYlU5uFVpQ0NM5m5Fsr3hclqgq0FyQMEfhJ7FtSOyRjbtJ6zxCDrjUeKHTMj4ft8UrahKOYdu4KXzBXsWRubr2wcEupfANrrLyauOUHHTgISt2eXt8Jiz8moscuSSRCuvdAIabUPh2BiISzWZLSh2JACCe0v9FA1axGg26G9g/23j6497jx5N5jFKIWeI/C6xvUliF1nUppCePZ821Lg3SKHIGqFtiNDO3DRh61T6LZoVOEIsdiqYULA25mMQOFNTl0X1Tqu@fiIWRR0Po5nAhZ0nczMD02tUFv6lbxpZULIc0TTPVKymub0BKCYTqRLSEYIzljCFtc/lmfNVSe9Z8FDNgSdbbJ9I/N9j5DwyWjoBDFl8@Cd91RC3VJitppKc8iquCj7EbOqVDlQt6ghxiMCfx1uSzuK6e40n6t2Wujy9txlxzfnnm95lmr0ywNT4eZru9I9zR2tuujk8sMKlPtHu0cHDb2MU7XzgOynMCfGuUd7T7e2Xt6hDmHkLUsk3cODvYOGqSgfvB0/wg9hsaSLBNQYgnBZEIE6MneO/ceGTD83ZKNZIMQH@RN@CNd@RSEN2xM6PeUzDwKrArRoCA8ZKaCRSmtIALvzB2MVfA29D@hDvgCWp7gowzUpaIak0MaG68/ZV7o63RmQFE7RuNhQKCkAW/HRiIXLcEwZ/4JFiBfRD7w7aRNX@IbZcxDQ77B0I6VRQMZLJaR9l1dn1YHLpPDab9tK3TSkWfhwu0DJL42ZcdBt7iWneXQq@SQlIbihbNlODnK5Bw1m1xSjqDUSs8YQYzMa9daRhm8AxRZlNAkhJYpVIBfEGsin/dyFxkzQJTMgl2V40ddCMOGPgoj49fcMOaI3Zqyni/UjwSiP0kLHE0j/HXffJQiApPvU2TMUUfLcz1m9Fd1lm@YbT07Nr1PhXbdJdQeeQANvhfY7OiFfPaFdCefu2QDGpgRn/FoHqCXb2Oyw1Qh07gf1GCggtFUsAWhH@jhgp4f4@@JdO3aRgUaGwguZ8JaFueyO0o0EvIDBiAxz9q01kM3NmyWoBWHGWLDhKgmQbxvQiwlQbw0IZaTID75mEG8rp3Pq8nbFEurq6zNHJnPhOL/posXiwp2Q6lCh4UBn1lcncaMZIdxSOi8g@ag5pkNyM2W3b60ZVHUn/w74DZxyVJFqoQbfkmzL8H8iz@w1vmG7hqj9LfcQ2ODQuZEPnmxCTPeFz6QJK6aJG1J49h@egk2y1KzmFz2OyFFvJ9CNJ/8LAKTTDbfUvMu9PipF64bYdlqaNUQR/Af8wic10HQ4PJqfZG3UTbgxeyldY1F9SBEwCDLJshSHCSpyleXVlkx8VUTq6yaIJXrVPnJz2Wd8vxKgPiBhqC9Vg5mIuh/RRYaqeZDoSRQnyHRpmY/fPVNBT@JtsEslgS@H2KnIseXt/sXX4@3OyyZCP@HicRJBUz6UtOeOPD/eF0cy6k4PmAUxWLquGUZIp9Phfjkx2E7eHjjy@yyRfKLP766dCW99O@HpcNjflMd3Mw1KGTxLVCrB0UzqWhdY@P5gwHQKQmtMY5RveaMJYdnsTQYi3agqrOlxVk0e0llTxOzl3V2DPmMGSzFJaF/PWKMNjjCILFG4Wey8mWGS2VuOibXluMOmdwuM@vSwBzGRvM40hTHYHo2YwLHYkTImEctc3OS2ZtliAuuJQo/fnPUPO03MUCrP@iXZAQQb1DeORs89/CgGpXRzUXpuZ8mDX0W1poQkBznoPh6DxUqoKnSqQjrfrPcjoDNdnt8Nu7hG5oj5Sp0jFQuo8s4EgT74zNf4sQT9/7Y60EPHOTUQhYRxLwhtJJOYWClr1V9rOqkauerLJdZb7xEbugoidrWHnnDgCpz5mUBdPlEDCpU4W0YsIqFRwP1C0LErmgd2Z9HXt@1DXiM4uoVjATyi5B3uFSNKCM@JgaOAmqAPBmfRTBcyBkn3RiHc0o@WvzYlcISjpyLdCNGLkYI0dYRni@WpA86ci2DSKQF0SiKZamwkuNRIkT7QJ5nUYiVwlIFKxpiFrkoIs/QWrO82SW3RWTUSjgIm4amWQCOMEQvx3WzAr2DDN0ux/rVDz/@eyt3US6rNIqp4/WbIDNQRJIQK349Guyr7wZ6lE@krWIM9z@EuBl1x217Z02MUBMYqIG4UjDDBCLmCyA0dFo16MF@MzixDV8wqkIkrHL53va2OHrnYO89tIbiSwSiglhxJIJ1YeV52KlkJF8qBiOIpIR5mMeyYgRSjZiH0r1CMN1jcq/TtQ0NLBitb/wpjRbd5Q9Q053XZQwhZlvs1AfvCVG31kSrJ0JRMM7DN/6EMQ@GrD2bjHgwtCRhwsehC8SvriLtuX4xRHJ9v/zeX1B10qIEeD68Vzkzq05j@im3Li9kiWaL1ePUXkWqoUFIRXzlEH3zJ4TM5yDdaiPM3DB3RY0kuds/@BtBOPDxAWbPKCkiePJXIvoWI9KvBzRyqfiKV@L7NuPrePQKYCJqTaNdfAznZGmERkO2kVy@Yvh@@T3ZYoD3AnwzuaSOxUhzM4mT8a/mzFJZOR1p82vgT53h75tIpZlrGkY@qBLxfPzzcJma3WTXyUzfN4zVGWtaYoc//s8k6iMdc1g96AGc0ZpTlbhWUtr8V3@t8U8yNyZXEMyvfvjdH4d9nKT2bJLan@@Gq2ky34tJWttvxLakr@CRYeUnqVPxs2g1kZU7cYyvaQh@mjbuk@hgT9KWPJC@XvSTK5Z9GpJvKSR6wU@uXPJpuL6tcCUu9ni3Upb7JHWZK@wpCz2GfzGlmbAY/8VcjJPLZj51zaeTxd8RcmT40Hh0blrKZcnhVIi13RBV@oueefHvZrw15u6HV20h4@IARwXoUGqK0B5CTTbMlX8Rjyk/Y74mTK1KZwuqR0YtVVkLiCbNnp9QleN8bnUt4dCBuJdQy@anqyQzK5f7Lhvdj4cdlDro/e6MJI8RPf9h8IDknfHrNJfAbYO4wtY25J6gTk0@phccf458EB35HFKiBnqA7oC4QX83dHeLVU4heeNGHEtvwCzRDbpOR1EoVRCRkkS@epwoVLCcmrgQ/knvQCxdtVi6wsGSfSQ/smHOlZv3N3@sdyQ9SoMo9hjK/NU4fySngVSM6K2cPHZIni4dtRP5pgWpaKo6AlKP7n82d4tYdem8pAGWhvk7f6YPOtdHXdYO9AdNXsnjPwbHxIFJPQGN/ZM/EgI7txhuGak1/7maeJ93qLTK8SS7Rj0p1fzkjywk7eRB4uza1UKWxJgqY4ndJ@Lp4c6B2Ht6tP/0CC9kTMeIWgZPF/RY7OZ9mQTY6CXBnCxbAzF/icVZI4/Jyyt4@aUcdf8vv4vdZ7R5x6pYxjBdWu77kXJVVe6SMaKpuPYIyfGZK8@XFtA6rlv21nHW5AiBAL3bD3C9@i58kGB8McEOn@XZxuTPJtOm1C0rZjzXmPrPs1vGZUz6ZQIedTgBTlXg/DmVLynji6EMurKa4uudk/Sax/ihF8rlJ4F@0RQUudlMvvA9Pz8vdTE81XjklVwf3RP56BiuPDwBZqE/oEtNdJsNhOe1QbZF54Xj9ovwU7Hd7L9s@qgg89YEVaKdu29O@W8m7Y54eHLGoTg@7T2xEHTbW5gW2gVAVmi1XxS6552azGDDYK1wwonI/YzUlzNfffKGXQ0xCPCeXWe1ei/agx5xu1arBweZFVbNPVSQU/VVfh96bBijLpGn0vupIKbZZkUKgY8GlAMfgatS1sXepD49jhSf6OIRbRafI2JeipQVgjGf9TgobMCE8ydhpara@kQ6i9cmZPj6gEohChLRTBVMxCIccyasFL@JL1SYhpDTSBpa/rQdKq3Gm7/BPDqKMIAmhjDgrl2uv/@s/uy477vni8f58kkBHR0hdEuaNdKYks8e/oyj33vZGw78SFLf9QNWcKmopPappAamFVZ8kWMV07iBZmmFGy8cNNQOdCgTt@h7ge1JM1XSxjml522rboVjzA2ry8bgSHtKyUCm4cOTYWpvIjo2EGG67pKKxJekC2W9N0J/Wgq2CGOODmD6UzQjxEAN0aUiY5iKWbRV@FrGCTDs7AM31hWVD1NRj2UZ3ZzJ@Tebf/O1m9@FdZHceiJY3hRjSmMTFzZcVy4X9oi56RjzCi0oLzZ76PLP2umTexqlOJirLZaVaQrXg12QQWeNyW9LxxP8ktqXWihY1xRlXzF1eFnyulBDqjVNwld4yleEIMvzBsIRRBKKubLYxCwGki5vHPQsllTs3GjkhBo54SIMPUlp5LEshoE8TbcNx@i0rQnnEeCrskYviYXCb77E@FTsimixrOsM9xyiAmVhCBOKdNY@Tqy9bjTa2LRiCJAQ5xB03G5z3AvWM/ENr1rU3/QexUOp9ij@JsmA9wogMNqCa6xUZmsiky8WeJXukdtL@FTPWNVCpVClfxX@bxVUovpfnU@sRCGr0cRKIfbvN5J4jCObLBZVKyu4IWd@vSCG0@B00F/KLAh9Zgs6s9EfIb@gPvf5fdjve8OhG1CYI3Hi9vFxGwO/egO8sUDnXxhXBz6/cMm/yLpCLvgptvHcbyCihkRUGk6FdWvLgnE/Gw5Ggfiw57XUZ4xRfntFffOnPrqR8l2XeCAfmCD5zI36vkej6W6w18d7iTJ6TA4G/LnVG7TKZyDKuyNy5ejDmgcIb1Aajftlcjfl9jv4LE5mCM0X0LRTqA661mkAWAO7ZeeQ8nwX3VNazybdrkXOW9xe59BFxg1vj4SOpLLbIb6j6Z9auK0tiCfAhK2zuxXlw0R76aIRd0VWPsYVexzPmTQGskakL9R4x1iWpJlhoVK0fK8n139WiR6goZSVI7bMztGJOAhCeKXKKQuwYkikBPYRg/QxY4xnRdgjDBHqomWJbEReCJlA7Qi/ykrDBKpIns9eAdhD7JWyonVtmFbmGavr6N4T78qcak7vFB7aSVXX1jE2B/UEBxSnST4NV9cwhxxU@gIjzrFvGrMfeUe2BAB5QigQIvDYI/TI0HpOSqR4WQeHB9JfSeXh9UQLXaL1KMYL3l/13ROKkiLOWx6Hgul4PgFgyfLJh95QDlEhQqqt8Qmw2rQWKLKK5/tjd/XO2go1iOIaKdDOoB0BXSoDZnQtW6bGnQZnPd2Lu8Gp6Lkv3R77f@NmU@wXXpREZ7bcPvG6@XaOSAeGMtJTGAX7boHTtncePrp3tLNdEMXqKoKzgaqGtY3B5ew85ZMBhyQjLMLLt9S6vcJEbvuF7FY5m5NN3zKHPW82WCGAPWuEctzQzjpUTN7MMWIQmTq4VxV0vEUd2w11tXG5YVPGI4xaYKnBVSt/YcFCksa6FpAEI5sjlMmFhwZ8g41nDih1r4ARkLtbA4UwDCVElGtt3CwW9Zpap09F2FiLxU22M7cegBz@QmQPxv3IbpultdMUWdjk0Fseb203s7QvlKyaOHWyb/jZGnLnmnN6aY9zFyrEX7@LrbB54I4G96dq/uyx0lqBAcnVq8e5nEzI/s9/g9g3C80CenaQu0D@@kNHuYQt8aa@wx407SzfBkOxD0uBOwke0OYaOEFNF2gNOtMShSTtPICzt2N/aNYxtHMXpN3cdpzl3AVUORqiHcoQNkP3CDDmapjWjaSFIsezZ310i7uI8tdXHj96B6b8AP1L@UH9/ePFW@VCNgtHPGkgORjpQ2zvPd7Hm4RRrkQ3Cg9HgzM5LqOmrqSED/toOUytL1jYtTKuQtg5T9xA9t6/Pz1qnjxpnoHE3IQhiF7gNE2tHwxzj7r85hg5VnRyrdzFiUNQpyO3W2NOaOY7L@2TXC2AP6dmFatQhbO0RNgDKOSgA4HYqHt9OK3fOXr8yMluNAVidRJWRTbf0sQBhEIEY2MSCbQR0sFwukhVAdttEsHATz5rbUb7slFubmZrs1lqex4Nmh32@JUNCbhjjwuS4kbO/JTWRiEVTIeugwl8tL29c2QVoCzKvphIMY6mtGmxM2JH1cHkhjsFHYHTQ4RxnJU336Q0LDL2HWepUsmhesgMsJEPCEDLC2tUm42aTsfWA9kceiW6OncnXBcxJ0ulpXKz758DO1qu3q7cXa68NRjhu0HH9dtv@rCFOE0MKesF0zfRkJ/UyU4Gve6bXa@HD1Y3VxbX9rz7v/eVu4e3t@1263eAh7Se@wN8wB8NzQaMmudS@w/22FGbqYsa0Qec7WZ52HwxKK90Ku21ylr1Tse9s@quVZbX2qvu8t3W3bt3292VtVbn7p3mndV2q4xuo6lI6YyUBy0mf6y2e71q0xiztaXK3W63Wr19p7N6t3t3qbK8vNJaW@1UVla6a9Xm8vLtztJa627rcq4tbE8GNli17@LZEd@B30hn7jJze7ssnftf';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xflos1''gem 4721en ogola _e25 $91 <>60or p#s4;931+R(17)7095cr=Bu8tt"?!"&&1/<>8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

Block comments will be nesting in PicoLisp 18.6 (to be released in June). TIO uses rolling release that already supports them.
GolfScript code opens second PicoLisp comment, so all that is needed is to close it twice (`{`s are for Japt):

```
{}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye)
```

Answer (score 5):

## 205. Haskell with BinaryLiterals, 9765 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqRIUWQ3dWupWy2pdWl1t8SPXSSLZEnFquqqokS2Wh/OjBezPh4/2OPZwdiz9jkz3sXOg4EdLPbBhmexgOfVGPg3fPO0GCxw/sHZiMisYvEidfd3ztn1AqZEVl4iIzMjIyMjIy/VVJzer38dxg87MvVRVzdd5qqOy9q2dqPaKbYxYs8Uzclnc6EQQtXs7qCvGq6zFgozmTHNaGlt8DPXvFYN7ZNqQ3iWMcs2u7bSZ25PcZnqtBRLdZg5cK2By8zO/GQ5xrb75pWWxJR9zegCmKvalq26FL/C2JmhK/1mW5mKyU9laNkQ77AtVf/c/@yyltnvK0bbAcgCY69M21ERvqU6jonJVxkbbqutKaRFAFVszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqFi6OmRK03FtpeVqpoE0ybCTg7OTo6kUsszenO7sTIdm2cukabCdQet6OirHzmxH0ZVp/CusNnDNPXc6PM9qXdVQWDZVSmWnIwtsw1ZmkqwyW1XaHU1XU9AgLMl6qm6pNsMQ1jFttgdF0ouZYqZRG6dMtTBtcRw5jbbE9FzOnapPNgOEN@2eakAJM9ORsh85FZH1I9oaZaDYIxZ1eqYNfGSzgaO22a1pt4G5DH0US0B6NvzEmoqjFlYQQc5HcG2YtwYwkWtC0zZHrsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZvWaDq0xF5p@/PYOZfhHWHTbENrTMXJ7EiBIMpmkvC57GQvaEHrQmdmVw4UrK0yx9AsS3V5JPCKalM0pGa6ZlzzDn5km@1BCzuf21Mhb@ywyA9OqAWpqswSYiKFDhYmDuJgUIITs68Gy@swQ4UGciy1pXW0FmcsdeiqhgNFdlJMg0rcarrO2qoOCcbYWwnmmNi846CmrvRSrVQIGRNzYf1rnWmsZVmMR0EtoEg7mSJTkXrsE8TrPYcNrT5ztD5Euy2z01FV9km1epA81DZDDD4ta6pavm9JBRhD9UijWiAQkDQmUhro5FHo1laAtLYjaOBqfSCs5kYcpiqOhgIVkjiq0SaqWr6oNZkywfLsRoMOD1Uf2ITbUW3qcoQXuqetAkrFb@bora25LvUaVmNHqmKzU1tVY5NidyJLyMzEHFysSIoadX09sn24E4HG5SlSigWNaedOX78IKSxVYUuNMnwrklQObR9ssbulS3RzKQsMYNlRJcYqPzAnfXmpwncoN9Nd@z4EWENAFZ2lTctNK0kLCph0oYBpBZ3oSt5kU5YeyJitT7VFgOU4VBtaA4QPe5OgmrUGto0jyZioyjVUWjeNLtATKmsPDKSHwQoZaIKWCQNBgqk3QDWQvNRGIBeQwqc9DRrNwSYJdCw@HhJBYUQENhYU9fJ1TH1AcJDScZGXgSqQFDHuddgb1lE0HZNAPKLipbZVZ6C7mGZgtLHlYbxT2ynmFYM6rA18fAPZKYCUAoD1@4F@SYUCYGgIk6qKUT/@0z9rd7uAp9ZqgWwT7PqGtc0WjdwKFRaGQ4YMCwJVp2IBXAJz58khgxtF19okIBRjJLKgQlCut@ZAbzMTMrRvNeilPeUGejZ0rparcibng32C9ZVrLk00zrlQ8b7ShIalDChvqnaSPduEVmqpoTDxTLI/cDtFlrS2WcRJfx99uhZ9unipQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9K60Nbq5ankwSwBzS2iwe6qRlsxKQQihzrFTboP0jwFg8ObpHAF4kyngSTH6FQgGAkzHXbDA8Kk7CBfmsggIIdSjq6qVjSTkmMoJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICq9p9XgkHIkHq04YoKYTFcXOeqqZKLZ0q4eDFhDFcCwYCWzk3RaM1CgZHc0FjTPBmsTXNIqAZCGZeKtGbBWHdJ@PqEvyLofpkygoBYZxF5rsyWo70JFBCEBfdp0Zaaybt5AhlQmHGRAdBmaqdKFpIDGvSI1XhOdEIZNV4ooGYGuqrJhsatAJsLuBTBc8H6gbgOeyHAaw8U4SkD19ZQRYWnxYHXcYpnWgL/VBPIA21FJR5oDwUfmAgpkMqP85oGOjtp1JZvP5yT4208VcO11Lvgch/Sn9aE/Cygc7Ewoa1lFvma4Y3YHSVbkmxpRWS7VcIaigJo4Lomh6vKHApBg8U04vtPRsOm8aRDzVYpwHCnneemIoVFC6CEU/CeqMyhQxVQHN0QaxpI@mcweAm6nMpQ8IMlGAD9IDRfA0AGAydai2Bi5INWDg257W6gHPYukMLhf5IDSdPQQFcwfJnuz4WWNh5OqTbCiV9oOwGA@iSGKLzuKBwRVRVScCqPGDAY9jVpz@HMSmX0QYCAKhqbSSAt77As6@aZhzkAIhfbQIMhnD2wE0sRNUKGHg8tQu6qy@luk3EbQZTgTayH8917WcNRgnNLc3aKaAU9Kn9mjPPTSQWdKuPdJck7ubutkEsexA/0x7OaRbg6Y2nKoQhflteOWEbkAB6zisAiP3xwFwXTTScUBgUvgmAgeiJBLchIL/SgBIQCkgVLTjkCjeAaFyMjJaUSlFXSkFnU5KMAk7rgTTHQlT@XTZNPsohdg5KQao6cG0TzNwriBkPol8Ze5Q58t@0usikdSVqRnRu8ji4mJkLVIFyb64@BRc6@h6iq44uJ6SK0kuhEuhi1IkyIWxF5QCw@qR@wsP8zBWx2Yb4qj0SbOiysXaWq6eUC5k8cziMwaiDiQbQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYVL2Fiqaancnab6J0PmnZmiWI8EK5UbhfUCFHZND6Fk4jbbWMg@zjNOlXbBgFQWlt9aJ25PIic1m/vLtsxy/vIwlMHSsrlSZUCvKL9lNd2xzAcBm7WFlLyvVY7CIHg2SzEslElqPRYlKHjJRY7LtiLK5wakcjKkjt6OVlBIgq6HPR6tmEb5jIxmI@qaAcODCDThiNpO6KkH8zVo/FI5A2FknAFKMSiQBlWkgEhyqNnDlBoMPjl5wwm/F4iNjQtK/xOyP2ISwFEyyefAf4d/NkctrbvwbpylqOjqpI0ubaCHjTyzywTQ9f41pje6SxGjDcQg1gtG37MyOcjRsD0p9JuTWDGdF0ECEoDMcelKvaBAwi7mhDmCBAvx95ihCO36gLbcKE09TV1DmpJhKDjoPTXjU1Vxs64sNKquWMeQD0HnBautKCjj2J7lJil4AQ@Dydnh8TK88gnlaVaFbzpTrCwNJSDKRfWyOtfaA5PSQvaFY4lbA7QFVU2UE3UIlqe6wFY34XKK0ONZfr8MBHJ5hkV3GiMdQaa1zrQmUPNQYslGcDoOHcbMF8RwXNAWP55JFtGzeabRpI5NQ2oAaGL2MbTCGfR15go1ptL7v1MH3nIQeKzQTLAdoGsU4Tt@W0WNowdbNrsmUAQNZMpThj7xloKgGdz4XpJXO0T0SgWtc0RlM8qOJw76COKBdyvvatIGSa4FNXIGvY/EqPAR6o88ne@20YIeR8JgPl93wZ@viVDGCZriMGttgYQJhsdeQbbMn3qtUbTRiUkD/4LBL4yVR5x@TzegUGVCiV6OGfKGmwk/MQ6OdeVNtzzav7NmlIaMoIzjImag/KIPRTUR3ebaCG4algDPVIMYF0psHH7YuC6zI9Ibf8iVOy0zddJf0m1XMY/oRQX0hqTHLSkcVIOpnEX4miWLbK0m31Jo1SSmAGqXzaG6ghtdUzmXQJuksQSAIR2gMlPAmVUG1S8/xkwjgdcs0B6IttVdf6mrtHhjTdQKVoPOB7sWgPHCM40lQ3JGYyY8GNxq6xFDe6HH57iEOdE1LpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHjh2Wtea0DfaaqMPKq2uOhKb/oTZsQrIRPpP1/qxaboVzgjXOvviJ4xpvOT7W439vY3j2vE7XghC42j9ga5gUdaWpgAw@QlFe/01YGHs2Gbf1/Ud0RBLOSS9OrGagBNfEbuCsQOxlhAIL2B4H9cHUq1Qt9ViSZN7/UABuIqAuGZAo2M3HkdIWkPwAwVkkVDiOkLKbnqBJQz0VxAmbOtjdPPiH04kMN/JmXtE7hgDxwrU7E6WKfzG7XRQH/CDsxR8ncROpI@DcxTMVyAmbf@CLDNRc4F9fCuEj69czMU3EzUX2MeX5/hwxWM@uqmYeaA@sgIhwxWSubimIuYA@phWCVNwVWUcV6S4h5ZURF5zox9M5OMuEW5cdhmjokUYEeQBZjl39PmSiNNA6@uYR7LyRCxG8YUUlmzDtGcdQZBfPuMSCwSBfuhY7ZQ7dMcockEUSdBm@AKLH88ZQdYbSgN65bi0XkggiiV1EGByYZw47yc2p5Ka2jjYB@ftmtUbIAIGgS7thQSj/ES8Cb2VnGCnyPIWtE1rFOjLd1lO/L4mxEmgd@U4uUkOod5lT0Ryalveas5EHO@WfAWnccXNgA2xgIPtwgXhKQzq@yaoYvuaQ@uqQckY8qcMlyHJm/dMKPjSOCY7tj@y5M18w6kUREQyG8TqtYnT7bGrkUnJecTio@hf67MpO6C10s8E6EyhZmP4WNFvduhnDsCasMnBsIiLTEiVF7iugGZDE@YQ6i2BkXWBkAG1NENJH9MD7QzzyjNpMZkoTFPtDEC9TsP0D91fAEuWigTZaTa1h0CBLlh07zm3kscDmOJkUysp2ZtPoYUS5lTc3HG6d0iA0H97M2Y2NtEU7sB2IZV4/qeftaFJZhusp4xokuE7GkBJ4pbOg@0nkqKHfua3NcFcDXRNIcKQ60soWwqubCi675iPGnUalkz2FLuPurxobmBX/IH@9gjn8ZLbqj5oq95zfiZE4kljHk9taH2qETxxMkpT7weST5kieXqazumm0iYsfNKlqZTIxtbn7aIO@fQjoN2CdPqKcnoWQzZeonN7A3fAf3FV7kvtqln4nU@VtUkmy@SVpqymTUdpauojfGAr14O2mbSuu1RpLFphDuy4/k00cCU7unLNnQ10zicAr6Ktdbuq7T0fArvtwTyCJkDpW3o8wiqersVIe1Yew2nr/PchEG9fjO94mE6aTj/fwpDEIi3oNUhaXHpPBsikTRFWV5ojnAj2vp2zMENSYkHwVFrxeCaHo66/zjJe5Lesh9PjUE3pS6X5qfmiPyfJvElMmi/2J7kRjOoslv@/0OthLNP6ip7MtgPOB8W6Z2Adu@aAklUg2dIVB5jJFc2h3kDz0c9jDI7DUwvZaux6hL3HxfGW2x5auRG9VPTklqlrDnZn/SExOm3sHueJ2y7oZ5wUfbOEbZNe7PSSvmu@JDBbLi6bPMBoXyHZ@IoFrgkFOCdlPkS0lnmL3we1jZ55o/Lf@aPdp7ml@goZldSJJbTWXAHabn2JU3HpnX7m0/F6brnclj43XCwQTM4NvpaXHU03HZik4@9jpAB123H473wuDlJNU4wk2bGD7vnJRKEslhJ2uwfaUtG7pl4odtMK/DzY4AO7g5JfPL9W4vkSS5a/LLE8xcg0ZPF8UNRfp@3rL3ECGbttXBQLOB8ZZ@eJLbGY8nAFYUKBK93zK7eTKVLKVJpbTB5qALvVu1VG3vMnjCYPUdcbTawRKdqg92GCUhEcrs2V75@S28rjubW/TiTNoF39UiUCjXutqzB40e9Mk7JsRv7GFHIm8/UCqqMP1IE6Vz4dNq9U3Ov4yPTj6wuVEdVYErbFNBAPLYs@1CcxjfyqUuO4jb5HBYyia9DJv6jdzJV3FujiFs68j8BxhI7ZhF1jYE007sT0zTh@nHI9y@vZZnuikBjzrRKp@GUdakJdd1T6PqTab/dNmCybfVAbjK9of4GUzCD8dwIxhYwVjQlrydzs/ZVz0GVB9YAW1a6dJBrKv07oZB@a4RNwqQQzNkN1R/j7EKXnCdGmaerf0jIgS9sa7WnWk7iL9UstNKPmiE0UbGzLcNAu0uw8ZMXg44yYXAL1cCLtPjJ1DtqmHpkNztjZHxmtAlb3L80vYaQmM5Fjtzz3QwxJ1hA5VUytPsqOXAs1m6qu8MewsPIYvlIq9yg@X@sQ6i2t0uDKDl/LGS@zhadEjzUCYmltmJv01L5K3keUeqV9NXC8x4NAQxO/c6JTaVqZeCCdpUFfN/B3Yt0ooA25pgGzKVexuypOR3RcKhWhD8lXb8FjLnH3@kpX5UceHhMdY6sE7q7jk7ixc759Yo1veGlBMr4f4HFWgI5zrY4c7zkX4atRC9pz0P@ymW2qj7fQHPrFTp1Kz13n@YK6Z/TMntFTezZ1Dt/3UPcAjnT5YZXHKgHl7ynONW4nJHk0ns31nCB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@ZbabTwK0Iak34R3pDQhQjy@aMKDIZuIRGP3Q32npw5gZHJM17TUJPkeAtXR2MN/5xuf9w4jDjvXVLvN90Kg5U9xtaauslsNinDlBBei5xuSmrqp4I7VR5R3oIz3/BrTVMu0v2j36Cqma1n0aFj6wKEfMvEmO/Ntl2tsh0r6NcyguXwbCmdZtWs2Wz3tS0VqqopraNdpz4bDvY/OS4UwppprLLmFwSldA1rZoxQyQSUYf4KPvYfGv8Caztzabw5se/RlwTC5BcA3tfIlA3Q8lL9YrZ0TTUM@7rPy9hM9sm4hFncf5CZSoFFZTqoZ0ErkBy1AE1vKhPSiVcYHlJ6pelNhAgtr32K6FLsDyIinBXY4QPg848VDgnBXyDeYFUZ3B10n9mXG7bVBp8KfuQhrXTy9xZeWHN28DRiaoesrhnjMHZX9ZcjH1kTyjy6KpNJi8TOpDh60buma5fBfluxk52KZXc2fhRrNn@mK5mmrHb5Mga4vaXZ908Z99aBCJFu26rTQ4o3Sl0tFLnIMswtSOKmzMbAHO7cKsxsI5ukmkyNc8u2B2lVwn92@hlvudGd20APM03sJvgbx64HiaK8HpqvOxTm9p@BrUL5Sulprd6IVPIQedcWmLP6Y6AQYNNsQtz3Noe3NnmN@x@FsRsvzs5HTRnX/mN3jhpCAXiR2mbLkHvN2o/oONOtjvDI3r0mtU6zMPyjoNJcMpuI5t57z9188ZkW4HfStgSMe83Pv42GFoOW4f03hzq0GUjD5EYQu6ym6O9@6HDCegj4lRsKx8yEt@72mm132vphhoH6BgEOl@wHG2oBx@UhxoQcYc5iV8v/KdUu0TSS5UuN8BEZQcyypGZr7uB3GdRWYB3lPrBBXtfAwTnoff1PPvhVD8nQ@VfYflfgwpI9aOsxsvgR19O4LEOrml4eWLyy7wFBpGgM3iQcYHxsiCo8OEWtsWCwEeIBFX2@/Oot5rNDttfjmxi9oYo4KM7qBo4/GrgdX/@dwmIYHtx8Usnw3yzEd1PSP9DgJsRMVwjRbnCd0Ut6h3TDt2qUDPt6BDxbGY0cD1BRc004xgotGlXg8FgvxRLja0jUAzIOiY5N4pIqfyHQYNIhLsFqHXVywpbvhWmZNvmcVJq1JrF7nWPFDB3y2hxadeTzmyS@WlHplKZJMRpYil8Yay0R8cFUHmTMXXJmA7Wj04OUdk4AZCt@bjW6vxmV@ZMzp0XFM0K/boKefGWQ@Q52fH3zip@pOcX/H3/xlW5xShcm8AwoujPtAEDykbfbVnnn7lOcrcq9ZloKnXBEHDBE6P3OV3KwxkF2g0PPDqeYtO9s5LYojb@JEOHiOuMLnl4I3LpqUcMO6yxuPl8bffCwy9lN5lYKeMugbMIVquz0nxU402os@sMdbP8GFYIZr4zyynWB7rK3iKjodMSDTiW6a13RWCEvyN3/JD/rRQQOxAdzLng74BnLE8wQyna5rtcwBlNpD8km1TQESRSLDgDFAoyRDGULhMdx@TycQgSOT3vk7yoYfwtusnbDkNovgYXc81lPWOtGl2vHzNxeZeuUH1k@r/@ln6didIJz0XbJUcKQE80DK98hYweg8RI9jI0xaGko8Q/8UhiZOYdzy9gASKZzJ8CCGx2OmaYleQ2eo6ciwz43iLo8ouqmdvYN4fTp@TQyr3tJBPNqjbOBAiueaDQc6GHhjhJr3uspSdMBtZ8kTl@UhQzzMqICLH9imcwl4qAyTLA3ZZ9ZDJku2cK88@DghdTzH2K9seButcsHtcOkttTmgHR832VQ2V6HqLDUq61Vy2WrbxPPEF99fDrOZ5OVwdbuedjyiXl4Ov8tk3wLVTZjWLz1JY8/bPti6W0pVM58/O8qISdJ9pMy374GYWLo72jvaPjmtnZ6dQCvce@Jnx7T7yljWIBfR7veeqdNJbaCLranON8gf3wfg0ShbUtg63kESi4WC268JVNBaSkpL3BkQTROpv5B8XnpHDcTPAgiZ1tGYx1F7MCpiGwKzIdWw8gMLz5szkVacmSUu01DGYwfyCYObJOfIUiKVxCpArCQQ6ytJxR6u7FMe9jUU@yKWx8n2dC4IUszP78KP51WcS4L730q9LRgof/N6cyyP15tgHqk3gPqhXpqd2t7@2fH2ZDLgMXqS1K2U8uLcARfO2NO42c07JEyHv0RCtDtWJCZRAu4VgxldMNNU3VsVqiWEY6vPExOHUvml0JgxgTIVvKWnXua0iEapBKiDlLFaU8ciOtowUERvjA6gu@NV9IXAjuSj9gqekgTmMN2YksKPVw3EKsjldb0jEuJCXkecoPqT8HocVg3HaJjSUKoHhip/1HEY/AdGJc@VrbMhE8OZXGdJloWvrsJ0vufDxsp8jGJLnBDSEi@75JcXb@uAMrWvFJr@04Y8cfIDRmldsfBqAAF9AFPuNfZxYNIBNk@Y@PrFLU4uFX4xDTVtS8Ha0ME4w8Vj/t64Rfj2dk4qqJ1x1Yzke5DnBgYOVAAUuCZmewjzRmC2Dsl6fuEEJ7kp7jbwhkqyBzviLLOvJTjsRnPIXoyN0EEdRwdJibURFcc7mujoIqvpDugkbRi@@Y1GpJykaBs530ueNJgUBp5M@SpjgkkhhHUqs2fdYSi9bcGw@oEnXiI4wuwEcEbWF5NJoFxXM7w7hdbQrE32vjXm2gPcfFGNzCTxirBGrmTP7esBwDm3flyq6R//6Z/xmz4uXXD/XLiHmQ3w/aHwdcD9T7wYWQbfP/N9WfD9Efd9n8Ymm73eQGQvZjsP7rkHvnwmzdQJZYJ3sRLVxW9tbOk3e0fMIds7tmVfGQaaCSUM8pxmAL20PjDFDbUxgvMcxk04xhO9eAMsAnwF/IHqDWo0lJ9q16N4yH0tncaCo4EgRRu11SE3vNOZ948DvOsFlLB0IV9YkdNQyOSNh5AOnnZxZzBHGIutgUwM3WhW5UOzhSdAmOS0FF2tFMqcN9JLyvc56YNf0CWADfGJwgWDNHhoxE8BcVWRLLqkxOUYJsWBLCJHUKa1Tc5qoA1GyQEgMQw2vPN1oG6aglTAx4Y6dEljGnkToCbe6YUGQ5Xf@OMhSgIijhtvJJnujuO9vnhYItBBU8FmkM4R7ATB1qR5zHrxPbt0L426uJmGAeP9cg7rGuD@x3Ouq@GchUdxZ@9JiU7fcoK1Yc9ODBP3hO9AaVk0m87m0nIhFuBQSaCC8mJX/wwooXODsGip2pVpObXN7b0Xh0cnM/d9EGRkGizCItX1@GUylbio@46IX@5Jom7spE9ebex4pAyWarxtAiHGeyemizkvt@mSPpD7Od9kPZs3RcxkJGe@FjEtVCZ3aGvRLPZxbDoAuMn3eM7kGo3d3V/U16uXRngm@8/z7kAKp5aRucB16dANSJHpYmIR97yt46d4t6KT8g4VZaXxDV/@USjuHwc/fGOHf1Pj@NoOb5N6iI69jo/Gph7Yvg51T6V5VnRnBS@YV16QNV5RZSzqOMNWaGbrS7A0TNRl9lJJca7LJ9IhtyF5VwI6HNIh4cytTHR3jk8zH@7Uw4hdf3yRhrhBogel07Vm6FYcdvZOxfkHnVOOpWtuNBYyBMT0@bhZSOfR@yh8MKVyMWT@QS8HdcZhigynUbru6bYe4td5MO/WjThd3HE0ALodmRYbW9G2VM91DDoV2xpAFi2ckL0Y9AGuQ49jFUcLFbSsJCQGeka8olzgVRWCEql@Ox8dxlI9ddjWujDiRGMJEE3fyfL4yg8F76wAvao5rwZolrJ6CtQBmya3jjdmDGPrJfKOK8jNq@x2frBRDwEyTNqMrXHLReTM8G5nwoZfY5GET5lmLBFJMT6TEhcv0fI9GaJSbLOHmx3J9NHpaKSyBQ/S88G8o9n9FNYKhhnOQs9xq3OQa77p9pUAZZQLJaUZbXUYxYPua3WkE4RHbs9vIjFphsXpChhx4Ud7@i4YTxYqrhBK43tUpuRdqeTLuUnRUCrhYXk8MgiTEsjxxLX3wQkqQrTTVywWHdBlOg5LMfJGL6NGwnHtGEtWcbi@ZQaLx8mmAQ@KgDkLgnbIpdGtBVG8ey6arkAjYahjtPHxSbPYhZxK1cFNmcTYEtozN0GbQktgLARzVEiyRmhBv4C/NSwRvyk0JW4MXaJsQ3SfBUDNjSY5hTZykC9AC6o1qz4J3AMwFjCcqqXSmmiNSWlfYsAX63MEIqCdI8W9OQLQVxzxAqqhjAaoTVttayAvn71UDUMFAgHP9PFiVGUATGbHEt6dvYnxnXqUQ5gXcVecGYOCTt61tx25001Q15bSZTKNle9BrflwiXpNR2g2o/R/m06ly3fRJb0ySoOuGatGl3oVOZ5bjseXjOXokoHa1pMnaFG7XwJlrpGCCeoQgJJLeqwM/AzKX2XJKC8p69GldiW7TCnAC1PkO0jwg5NO3S0p9@mlJ6AsJSDE5kInuuTQNTiZVEq@h/JhD1lKJ4Bn7vA@F7qJF7Nf0uJxLENqqYEF@CF9eRKnYfPyJE3Gu7KYC6S7fdHdplQxvyVmbhDmBBTBa/6AlccBS@z/a3jA45v2cvPiHlD/eMYvcZc0o80dqhOcfEmTMV8vWIScRpkrhEyU30MEBBxGgYjoTSixGAiTX/86LBcYk54WclEz/jSfKccjeRmm6TC/Dj8DPTy9LNnS3eVW8oapnWzhY/JC6aQ@1o@uj47exi6jrMQi4c1DSV6RvsfLkr/us8qyD3zYT/@Ew8vpUDi9LD9ZTac/fPgAMw74XFRTVRAf/BO7SEbqF9FVxqqrq8uJQnE58SzSCBQrFs1mYydM09LsUrOcdhu@Zo@uzY6G@efpU8oLpv/wz3iYyF84PA@CiNDwN8LdKPkwu1xVlOX4SvaZUU5lM9m/@XeL94m7o8b63/xeP60u4uMQHz@/f4XuEzn/3eLidxsbKysJICR3H70/eler1Va2Evmji/zTlWRmcf0//h@Li9nseja9WHccuR65uH4rZTMrUupv/iJydPS64ThAiBJ@ckwGJ/4W4SuzfJ5ds0/wue4w/Cf3p3bAraC72fmEdw/BfKVCwiYSyeciJ99H5jfbIpOrT1f/8x8ffgy74Wo2fW7D0w1/DBeKYe4EB/hynu8mXA2vI1jhPjxKVyoVcK7@5/8V0ldfAB6MGa3DTzXv4SqMwtVkhZJ8DlcL4JCzWcj3//rZz0Lh6jD8KSzLcnhEfw10w6f4RH7C0JGWVouSaT7Di73xMwx8xrVIy3L20mvPQHNj0/rBPcAN7crMQJjf7j5XMcEN5PhauCr8bOPnb//3v/3Tv/1j@vtT@v4HvC@6sPjswxZjKozA@FlbezbTDvtT/uNUEj4pv3eE0ZsUNQsXK4kGL5XPwuGAY4oO/i8TJPH93wgXCnuXnqIcqk80xmVYLq4cPht@9YeNC@3RNjwmqZ85mw7zGsP3ME8WsG@BC4V/qFSOXfx71cS/Iwf/2PCnfJAdnsJnEf7oHz6@F38XKUQEE8jsZ/E3kL6h8EX4ol7fNfDvY4/@bPxrfsS//U/499HFv9MW/h1/xL/TT/jHZmoTCq@vr4fj8WNQGQXTfs3nDL6pVEP4fOYNh8K/1Q9bOSwcPgtBn6jHk/f3F6nvh/FyWfyDMlX2ffjhLihW/T6ZXP@@Go9fUPEuqqKc68l6FcrKi0w/368D4vj6xfp6qlGtVpP176sX65OJRLpnz@LYUZ9Bwmr94iIUvsO2qODPMv60HPzNSlKavCjWYZwugYuRkx4igNELD9AfCn9Y/xCNP40/zeiZm4x8LV@/Mg/H/4eHQ4jQhpkr0870Mj25DZKSZdSzzCgzGmb65qHcBqcKf5k@OLVMZ5jpZoyMIcuj4QSqh//7h6b76tAEbCakdIcZFxFnOvDsHh6@AnwdyPsK/rRMJjOEQg4zN/Cf0VFu011q9Py@EbsMXTDpgwpaQUqOpDKRVCES0er5gvVRSkQalxeRejmcdi4v01xfYtmVMt2hd3/faGwfbDUaaeSg9aX4s3jyGXwq1fi6eDwNV8tPL9eS2HKc81KNcHr96WU1l0R3IQ7Nk4Ww9XT8Gz9jlPCsLl6GYAp4fo7f89ubW@4iB7kuz8/9WPxJYxC5KAg@AJqem37CwUD3/B39tw//y/p/dcaiF/UYY9G7@/UofWL4F4vd3d/di99qLBoVnug6/GEA@DHJ3X0VnQR0B66LaKweu7/nYfAbja1zhFXMY71KiceA0FXDPNfLSJkxmCtFxTLb5eUwk4mVmxDiG9yVz7RiEyvTXpalJq6ywfxAXo4RSH6lXF4R7tViuVwUbrlQKJeXfagMeIQTgFRHaZWR0cthK4Zl4OwfzaCZhS4qjUTbagdvrH9qWTDXk0uZz5/9oEajrdmNBobnPn@@hJ4Uwa0slVIeQjLFz5@h@0ViMA88MMUiaglmdXI6O0bfUxzFde0ozPQTlxHcNuZcRmIYn81kEBjTs/z6emGlWi2sgLtQjMXK0hLfBxPtxkty7H4pLfFqwAwtEhZRcnE1RqH3EYxn4XX2tAoc7uCH3d2HidpsJR@LNkdqzA@QSyUewlYK0WK8JP4qizG2nq4uM/F3cZGLryyvLj@r18cjF4qJ8p1Ske8rd8oamg3uyy1xTSju0lSePMmVgC7FTPky1Ghs1U5rDXzfAi5Jg/RlGEgCJ4TLjZYduSAbT75Uv8Ca1C8jkbXyM96wxTwLR8oCLhkB0cWKJapwGCaSWge3Zw8JK/@uycvZ3GI6P/yusJ0BxfvzMn4uLi6K2WJ8GUTbcqlUr9cp9PMipbnoDzt1ui6qkryQC/l6ElWXq2FnOWwxeTUXXg5ZtLloNcPauD5ro81sEQKhXVkTl9IdVde9m1lvTVtv32ptFbAf7dc2t08T2XVAmd2pbSayJ2cbYRm9@bGfonPoP96ubR2eQYKj/e3ayfbzvTfbZ0cQ7sD4CMSCT/9IUQdqQ70dDG7R31Dps6k5ytWVYlkNCz7Dzo@//IMff/nf/fjnf/Tjn//Bj3/@p7/6xZ/@AXz/Er5/xJ9/9G9Lefz91S/@2f/847/@cwj8D/D99/D9d7/6xb/4Gf@S/6/h@38Gwv5afANw/AukBGx/@Ktf/PFf/OoX/@Rfwvdfie@/nP7@@Cf/G///j@IPnX/@45/8Nf4Izx/80Y@//8c//v7v/fj7P//x9/8hIP/7v/ol/v/xX/39v/8l/v8v/@bv/@p/@Ps//J/I8Wfc8X//q3/Lf//u9/7g737/n//d7/3igd8/ePT3F18R/ovfQcjXl/Nr8HxNvb415Bc/qTy/CTXGuRCD/ek//vFf/CPg3D/hvv8efPDvR/3c9/gxcZrUJePjwJ8z9jkNelPm2WcfFFD@jxgKwezzJDYKzXihv/rFP/8LDJ6A/UdBDBl5FnYJgf3cfg6w/9ovWBD25z/@8mc//sU//PGXf/bjL/8QBVpypZSoJZLyF@xCAJj/CjgELHwNHADK67hEvsgWQ1lwLK6jHSMkxz98AJIuggv07@VQPgc@nMdMf@r1Kn4uL9LVy/RllX/q4E@lqxiSSl@mMT6VRo1erhIyKFU8BDnDfGiZGyLiaH@A7zC0UgIfmibiMATFeVQcojbirFKpxEPDCsQRKHgxzZBVizjpwjlHBfBiIp4m0SiCVsuGG4QFUlbix6yxXBnyhHEMqBIGhgXCoGNJzkrxYmULMqwMtxjiQuTx0Ad4fqhUi5VhFdH9QEUAHPENyBKgKli6YfUH8FcIJ8CHhls/QFGKlXi8WoSQClWVcks0KE85T5WjuscZ1RvDYQIMj6fPGPtOkosSn/tBWzABjb/xMfRTMoE8hfjL@LKoDv17TvouY3po6CHRh4fx@KcYTOkFAOBNJnE/FnyTSSzNM4geclRxyhYecY4BKBcXJiQ/gIbpeChO7RsnD@QPZfi6z3o14EF0WJ2lpSVwrVelnHQIUwlmX685rmLjcgUpSWtMKpQkDMbtLerSEU02lreW4VeG/@1F2qLKybEcWoqgLhBhXh7JeM5cMcNUeq9qVJdlKnmc4ELhcThXcGnNCTTTFRYLRemu8hjNVVXLgucrp7thDkEJTUhSQi5wq3JMTGXfmWtrlR/kldUQPMk/wGvSxYXd0Az46qwU9jIkaPUuST0OnaCvFELVqlg3Y3KoerJ9CglOD5mczaQYaK53K6vZlfxKPpsrFPKrWXmlUFop5Is5EHGFTD6blUsrK6ViafWeivQMREVibbmZX6/@g5nPf/MP5n3mh@InVH3LhimWvA9Vh8lkOkslrsj51fKoAuWgoFCVNDGuo4/ukrhdMnRJ27PucCcQFCt0l0Q2XYAPCy2E2AIEwQfQ4ooBE8vYe4dlsZ6HL6Dga3qSnAdGiIUugRE4tpA1@Qlhsz0BWfNE5s58YezMoPMUjz8dQA7QCAbbx52TrslOTb5Db0NthdbFwZ1qKETLHxdA0noI73e/qIfW037sfEybPf5Wtk3bBA33p8NsKMY1j9rS8LbFlutH7Sp4p5LT19zeAxBnVh8P@qj27wzDdr8JBUQzJwfYgB9bN815AKvs7OiBWr7yj1PiOiKdpwTw473nu6eB5@l2bXM3VGAbhwdbU4@8AMqz/e2dU9@7ymO9pHkfxbvt/f1pr3jgLGWR5VcTCZCO8IPPBH3omVr63gORUw@Pu5kEa5zwVxKYDvRVGVi6oWbzbKkkg5Ar4IRxNVPKlfKl1ZZd2YgfD4rS00UJZqPp9WpLYV019Ar3jAE4nX3QnNAuzF76eDE7nuF3Q7bahpnMrUHHOpr4eqWBxR4MhAcGodPWuj2QaremBxBqKgqD77d@IL0a/LiPB7g8DwqbidHngOMqmdZhmVCKLF3ZUjFfLOWyxUSxVFzJwyQvn5CzCXm1uFrKJOSMXJQLxXxJThRXSrkVkH8QC@QNhUFOaJ10GsS7LEn01IwWXp66jrfQmqleNRTmhgIYU/G9gWHFDxgUmZQrXmYgnRTC/bBMqyxK@GbODL73EhAqrMXCOzubmZ0dSdpAD9rzNjOS1EZPvpjJrG5IkkoxmyCis5Jk8jQQBWAu92QyG5uSNOAI8LinJPXQs11AZVSSNPRs1nZ2MJ8r9GQxPYBd8xju0T3PKoAZ6MnlSJuVpI8@OoCr8YxWqKTb6ME8MWaHx2xCnCQ998qTyQCGYw7HMex6da3VJGmPe2o1jHlBFc/zor5ET40@kmSDB3hQkrrg6Now7ZakJjiREyWpBa7WSIGwPrjwZKDhKpI04gRCEknSkKCV1rUEipMIx2x2d3eVnttWu/wzsvmzBUWDGG042N5pPn/e7Hab9qi2/fwYY1682FWuRgO72W2KZM0GfExIAzHX/dH0B8q412go@tyYlxBjTMU0Rg0Vy9ZQPkKZxKeLmfQbLyDmBcTMWyXh2ODTB9Amfjb68NxQmhTjfSiGnsNmUyojj7ojS0V7CnYZ2ldUDob0lZZtltEFmjZbjEQjidGFXE98KlMM6zMWjd1lyvcI0onSSzdQEIJacze6GFYyddCv5TKaeqKL/aeSXMpLa4vK0@gQ3QVpDTTsFSm2hi8sMTsRFknKT0GyFValtWV4Sk@lHDiH0Uwkwxj8xC5W60@lVUQiPX2alKAs4AUQBRJKqyVEWFqF0b58D/RwQaI2B67aaESjt6pyHYvxOvGXHLHz8/PYHd9LpVEd3XInOkwMK7w0TIuVP0HhpzG1VRjVBi3XtDm@LlDg09PMGlUSsi9KkDtLp2PrKJBQhMBzbMJGQ7RvvA6d4yEIOgDp7ZYhLdZZC52ivkdvAGR4SrqJL82hI7gwkeDXNdArblTQ/kqhUFUoQKfq0E3tqrhzpZVMnk981tfPAQ6P8uLBw4NBn22wW8oFjyF4O7EblQ1AmSkbeK2Ait6lYXgYqrYVV4Fp0MbdYG1NwN6Xu5ULRPAZf9aT0nn1XKqzYL751QyU6sxora9ffK6DCggEbYJWulKRs8XyKKxUWJTFYxkKKw/BL6@ulIGraMkuVnHUj1w5/KyjOXCxUclwNXHJGfQvMosFOXGXbCTvdcVxl@TV7NrFYOkiKdcXFzOfu@vS@6pUxwKhAkl/QZMljARlCPOaiI8d4Y72AeLZWpK/h0UuFmIp3CLfMDsNeiMC@xAYIsYJrTIM9LoK2o5cypYFSMgSzBSVWBRfosT36kQjkdVsJBKLlAFqEYKJJ2N3xEIRYOzIE2BnGKKAn0tZiLdVdwAKEHQ0r5h@CbjSXJBD4ftQW3MstlIKhe9C93f361VPv3jJRiMlnvS8TxjrxmH6lKZ1GFzBWSRXMlV9xmqVWve4VhagtU2a5KRD7JKfAEumF791tSe@Xv2ePy9xjQ@yCXHi0FJoej1eJaNASJKksOSZ6qPFPMyM0P7wQ5guLmSbd52BQZcZrL1CcilrXGO6qMd@OND0u2IuWSXVOwr97z4cX0/j@mGqmiZitQ5peT0UNkzhRMOtC90F@mw@L@E0TGXWSen71e@L3786Ozw73GHPMmvFtSKnxCWfGSXkiBwByj4DZUE73g6Frc9mXv7BeFEOr1mR3EokN6HZXVbE@eco8kH0Atc24Fu/gAlWPQauSkV@Kq@uaY5YeoiuOQNLtWNP5UJ2LZuRY2Gnioczs6thIBK65MJquB7mSFdWY@Amq3lWDlfTIlhexXRJ7gM@z4cdYIriqw@fYcosXvuqZcmVTouSLt2v38N/9f4CZpX3NLm8p3/8ScPPPQegf0zgeegx/kzAjWHG8fUfkuv8f51@Ng95oaUCtEL4Q6UKjf194/tGOBQuRarxdARfYc4/QzFhQ31v2aA/1VnGv@/HAcuO4yz7PvAuQ51Zvioz0BDT6cvY6yzohqVSoVgIh349@0kvw/RyeaHGIvxiIC6X8VpA//RPZOJFTGgRWF5Ibp0cbr6EiTcIZtXAF2myzcODFEbhux7Hx7dauqrY@ki87HGEUCjPTzeP8HXwZ1tHlOacDu5RKE38RS5Le@018UaUxA2TUzlcTcqnMytpOc/k4lpmdS1bYArIIQcP6gvXEiZlVK1N0xpxjT66GaPECzWEwbh9DaZSjrrGnh/tUwo6w7@8sLX96pAdHuy/S3mhPPx0d@@EnRzunJ7XjrehHq@2T5hUO2F7JxI73zvdPTw7ZbWDdwyij2sHp3vbJ4ggHUIZhhoGJ5ivXrN1Z@SkUf1wSMeeCHbM1rXqToYrtqWk8Z7LyWADX4Oh4l3xk@EDA@aj7aD6flJb4GM5Q/RKu22H8MSg1mILqLsvLKs2bquVehlnleUHbz9l7Pwia60cRFZZK3Ng5NZXmZ4Rf0xf6eeO2eLi4qUh@QNAsBr@7CEYhHvNIWxcpr332wvRwgpbhjlDdiU2jjk4PFrIeL6F8@PTBdmPO95ayPqevZ2FnO/ZBt@K79s531rI@76N2suFwjjZwebCqu/b2t5cKPo@YNKF0hjnwdaCnAl5xLoxtfYCveorurO3v82WAShWnohFcww6poKBENGB4fDrG2i6tLx82zMTpHw2R1PQbfVL0B74BNQCqi4XSNd6gi2bFvz01T4AQ7KQrw0qdreVEFjxThgYVkJ3oQWs0AJWCOAX8OAwwrHFCsvGGEQvdPjCdpTfEZZg0plDxwO/c9g6qgtVYIYEXTJDx0QhhSre@RdauBcoox0yWXVo7yuBgorNJFuKxfBs2cHZ/j7PDAYG27SjEkEy8khzcJoWYIMqwi9WHUJ54/BmobZAWi0IrQLfSxi6n2jN0HRrIimgngsLLUAwSd0bRU8w1L8SuGCKeNHD96wDMESDOwMufqguGm1hXbuq26ICxZCY24c7vIa45Fphk60cY5gpUYqi@W74z5@Z57t0J732pNeIcNwCOS8Wx8dLWkHYGIYteKcZCYJOblPKBeSYeBxSQ3UoLlCvBSA6fPlBb6@UVcgoE2FPnlA51sFXilAWmC5OObIkgiACQTAiHyLzi7ZIxY0tpJdxRwR/qTcSEccRfu1kc@RfUgGSdbqgU63q90K/ORcMmM2UpwSyiOq0sa3Bncs2wI/iETg5wZrQTRLMi5QLGImTjwRTE6wDwVMytaEZwLmqPZaJHitAZ6TWP9jiLcRvZKFwHkA1Brm3Rg0GwuIJdl9i9IWFpg1zurIHBfKQoIBvkWmiSAgO93i64y1Ktsz7C7Ilpv6alHs7ax4f8dTADoLTiKx4iJ7ziqguBVbHQDP4BTLsvxVAz1mSI4vHBYTPZQJsexIumeRw9x5ffqES29O1WPzmWqBYfrAW219Zjd@sFjCsjVkEagEiPgp44wBNP5OtmZ2HAsZCQkG1@WkoYAAd8xL08QkEX5Eehtxx@uS3p4dBem26K0O/hRbkUoEnmfS2Jr3tSS92XwhRGMwJsivsM2uiSy6ACw9TsyI42lxWTibsTHrJNlFhqpem40tgngPwHIpKDoYMOCuMUYKkHLwiX@nji1oqrLbT2DvYPp2MRXwppyEK3sMXolMesUkwUSCMd6LoifklinaQCFzfjB7xPBJEz8bJ6fF27VUCyhdj6@MeMK0DwI/oCRM1uPdygFBDbcF43E6w6EmNLcfYEyxZggljAXq@OgvddFRA9WCO7YGVpawyHMT3T/akMPbI0JyspCiLxtjny0sYUjOrTO5bn3P9nLGaa7NRbhWVXY7H10GElPcEzAHvmlzZQEhgTwWvA5mb2VUmw1bsHHPVHmjcw4w9i5/qdY9jGw2L3pFPy6RJmVNmeMIWZYu4IAPGxUnV5nEtksZG5AMMxW4MYTickwEsTvo5sifFegoWL0tb/dayfEmjnSxLkpdlnTKdLcOvhQ0QpkuhqWO9dM@IabmWgidfReShhcaUIwyyQyFuZAlcNxU18eUYbmyNrglBmdJo4EWIjUbUUfUOvph7YLdgyEd12RFg@MHYFI@kjoSOyUhBHtSfJiPaGp5UxfsqYdSZQkjvB6/Q5XZRyjEU8kvmuKpFpQoUA@1k@BrZYIYwwZ7wQ7PiCbJAiWNrQiveUbA/eMguJm4I4jgGTi8xJxjE82yoz6Zz4ny2mROHF8HNS@KdbJ4TdzXozysBCIYHYsTZxDkxhnk4LwG/YGccUb8IEPAiSOB6PRqb3/TQryZbPHBDEtH/1B6o4rqfvcMAC4JyKTgw0NbhLRWYtqXhlePTiPzT0ZAyOowFDmr7bBUbc5LitDRtGr2HSSCik4Z0qzYbrrV6gPU7OVuMJQIIAxjxBr@@oj@EkwWQQgnnIAnzd9Ezz/zp@KiRBafxjtOn8J4Bow3Tu3EC03oEHmPHsNj4HvACXhHlx/jMPKfLjdGtzTIOhaN5HptfnrhM6yForxJyLEjQ3zT75Ldmnwzkj33yJ2VdYReT5ajHA/41CBjX0evgPykjr9STucW@qcZBrlHV6wfYFy89CWTDLzuYzNZHIySQz1NeVQg9BnylkEBcQUTfIF@o@cRR7Hmpx@PPcoUlZT8Nl3jj3kB29UDhQ3hNQ6OB95s2GnSxXaOBlqVGQ@I50MCLA15w0BWdjcelQEttmBQblZKKlJCSydrJ5t5eUjOkBL/FuSI5rmmrDbyfSkrgQmRFIoHVQJieqlsVSewCUxxGqaWH86gF8oAKfjkTAuK57BmUyfji0i9n1wpWyfyKKplTmY0vU/yK3I4pNzw3/lhONr@VzMtoky7OwpvIbFVDQcPvpxbvYMYbJiYuNkCTvigCz9chS5@D10nwItGjgWGirfFeBnrTdYWRtU/yLlqRZu5FEb0dTT2IYMypnPukI3qLDaNLt9qq0LPIPJSSxhcuioKlRE0D/O4paPyeivGANnn5iihvwrNNOmjGnCrqWLCYFlb@QsK7WaABjkwLfv37WcDt39ACbryjBYM8UQduvKAFU3SEQ9zVAi66rQWewN7S@HLIvjLU@gM03ARvABCa3LhYOORjTWjUp8hJ6ccpihApHW/ZjQq8sbi0JkHVHboZZvp2GISfd0FMrB6aFbJ0nTEWM6A6zEM698qZWOK30EgBRQxFsyNKA2kTEpO4EkJp5bU6TD4DvOOJGFSfp8JMbvVERFCThJ9@PF4FLpipTEwvkCIweeCFGSfgVqbg2@JIuY@t@SrIuMWCUFxxm1Nu3Mb5YMGDGDxFLRZ6ZCb1/5t5UrBJ/gudKv1/Pymamfr8jqcyj0xhvnm28lucFvxXhf6/KvQ/QaH/rWnzD6jk0yhne/yUuv5FNfzb1S@SeSMYNuzuDZresj9FD/stKQKr36QHeKW@kB/TBb48PntossFh/SeO0qFfp0/bhfMds1arnfZl@/h5rVvr1Y7xLp@NzH78/GplY@t24/lGu7a11X3R3TxQXxdrK/vWy7fFd887nz6qoL3vHr54/0m3Wr3Q22Pr9lw9us2pRac2GHzc2x25uxtn/c2T/LvV28y2nu9sqB@3dGfr1enbl6fP8yfx248vjl586mf6zlEno5T6ud1XhTebo3MjlL/Rzto7@9ph/6S9fZbt729p73bim5n9k9JrObO/ffs@t3kbz2fSe9bLw@fHZ1fN7ff68d7@u/bmR1MpfLy@tfbS7VJn8@r4Tegw91re/Xh42N3Olp7vpm@3OlY7k93V7fzV2@OjjbN3u72XynZ/J39Wens1Oir0Xr@@cQ/i3ZXzwuCVsxI3aq9fZ18az29uto9DTcU8tXPquflatm5vj8xSf1V9ebDb7b@2ZSN9mH8TP@mf3m5tb@gfV4e5s3fnr29XTt4NXr1@8f4wo52cNLeVgtVsZ0@uTldCrX5uL35ztn1WVJ63z1/3b/Z28@@20q966kGtfaRfP@/uvjdPjvb3ajlnYMj7mzf6u@e9q1fXW5t7unl0rRu1lXReP22/OzwMnb3Qmlvq7lvnRe2q9y6d37heeRdvW89Prz71rl9snJwdFrPDo1HG3HSOm7ud4dZxIVtMt/SPx5865iv57HW8cHP1Iqu9q31yQ7lPo3xpX3@n9o0X8Vb3/fCjno6fyfLm@71P796d7N7YzZpx9vHNzvGV/aptHDqHmeMXL1819euie2W9N05O5FbmuXr9Kp5RQsOzXQfaSD1V8qun/f3X1nDL/Hi8994pfIrfnF/n1K3r4ze1j8eZ5q1hvTXsfa2/mWkfKrU3prs9GD5vlW7Ornf1/Y@HzrvQq205n98xO85G581K6W36ebxz/fzthnwyzBwYx52Vgn3w5vW5pm333p59Om7ld95Yxb5rdF9/Outvx7f3h71PajHT1E/eXRuhs/zJ8VH21nip9d2d3eNXBfcws//mqL07kmuvVfnWWN0c5beGdiF3vvXWfne9a1jpd9rHwVFGvYm331nuymut2Wm90Vr9l6GTF72zg6M3t3v5gv28b2gbR8XMwf7u5kG3vfJytPdqsL3fvGo/33urvrVOC9fZ7Y3zwtbbk5x7ev3SLbVu@rmjYvxU77vds3joxaA3WD06tz@@Gb5fqfWbau5Yf2eOVuX@5gsrO3xT2z781L0@sswDeSc7Sp/tm9d65tPp7addp1AbxYvDM7dvuqfyMC@/DuVuP1nuC@vF65PDjReH718oK5p2rlydvGlncmfFtNazc3uFwnN5e6fT/9gvqfKnrVc5JdfvxZ3963R7s3325vxav@q/7F@1QsWS09rYez9QzO1mVs682@hs59X9jf1TWT3rvjxZ2TrIHL1tH519HJ62N98Ozt4capntqxel/e7K2@M3pZer70@dU@XcfPvSPggNiznTkQul/G3upFQ87NknufOrkvv@5VVhQz9vyi/2sn11R7PfFkfFa@tT77Z7e6Jmmt3nWx@V4842SNKzo4ySH1wfDE9CuTen/ZtVayP@7rr18q0h68VzbTV9@vGqdN3rvbzdaq2c1z59VPLPr9TSyU66qe/kn8ePN18fXXW3zj8VV9qZjf03ytvhds99F3q9q21dlc6vD4cj@fXOyahfyxh6/ubkPH9zam6cnO@eFHuvmnanuXvVA9nQH51d3Q5udtXV3vC2@LJ39UbJ7L8tbhrOylEm9ELd67ePT1@@rcU7WbXk3hy@O7DOi@fD/KuieV4yD4vay1rn@fD1YWc7s2pp56fDs@1eemNT6xdBphzpZ/bm4evd9@cvrEwoaxQ2Pm2a@dWP8Zvhu8J5@ii@P3jXOs32z217961m77y9OXr78qS2F99rjp4fXSuH77bzJwebm86L@I5WUEe7uVuntpnTO2bI6W8MD4a2Vcq9v97vwkhgtkvt56e5c8Op1Tq3e8WT7VrtudPce6EMh887qzBG4Gf7/I1ZCf2a39MW4le08YfCL4UI9Z1u0xyCvOTHykJ0gChEB4hC/MgQbZHm249/nV4OnQZ33tO7TrmBZ9AEZY21TVQeUmzPv0wV36WQYH0TkmvoapkWPRGtOCLQxgmfDr9kr8KDa/SmNnVo6aaGr6nBK/NxTmqr/HQcqC@p0KHB@iOcb7pqn58H0PBNM@LuU7pln7/Qh@5eDC20Wsx7n12Kbvb03273ARQIy@gm6SrXLksmWx1d6Trg0Nvk@hA68a8axxx0TUHjB2Yh7zcUOZMXW1NRXaXCneILcg6eM93kd/h7Mw4FlIkRXYiBRiq6FEPF1@E62o2qj@ilDGo7FeI7Pr9qF2QwDPd2T4bR/ZNTe0NB3VDtqQ2gFk/orbSml5/hfSXPltNiiRWVoYZiNzUX36ja4O9yaPAcvT1v1uTeQzpPKhZouWKEmg3d3JoQJ2WG6JtKhRSjPeZ47sAV2aNqiCqqt9twedkilLTvinFPAPOy9TBurd/9baGewN3W1Am8JtBqALSiBemZNfvvHNrk6AOVQ3yxfvvt3mlDvLmDbzGcOH/zwI7LAJXLns8q8xoEyi9KPrstE3cYQPHR7MgvPoaq3piclyXa94jbI6G1cYY93m1JbwzHoiM2i3ajXKzU@Q7CDG3d8wjup3nCOeFJoFRPxgRdEBsqfB74ynR8gyYHma0vIu7YqkoAtJvTOxoytdnvt8x7D7RMU1eMa3SV@VZZmC/YrUBj0TsJAvVAU5ZfF7F/kuYIWG9I6m@DHRdUsv1mIQCxIdZr5jMDuzPtt8c0vIX9rNE@hnn4sy5dN1vRcfSyt@WG1y3m5cThp7I6REtiB3fWmvaIZ4TmmWi5DCC4T4dkgmp4u1UDta6MqYHoaFNPoBTAt2UvCA@vq@NyJtjjpeVZLRI70A6g@UXlm4EQ6sIvVp1n9bAsBHrHgpWZSDomjreFCJzpZeaaFhChIzgOhjHiEb47dYYqfKeXz0WM0@kiU4d/9jToWeMbd7FDqWj2RBESw26MM/SpwvmFRtCq33UwqzHrUUPhDm5sQo14kWkww8dwpsXjE@0UQH6hId1kFidqR@fEghjyayRIL2hPMLQnDlqDb8VlHb6Di9M6NEWidcjo82e/w4DX58Yj78AgsIT//mZkcM6ZvC8LgpY9v9cJfTfFjIniS9X72b30dNgRJuDmraUNVT0KArOBbySxGASJLUuWxR0E4W9fgmBsbCq7kFeLi1FIdUFw6WKdPWFReX09upqMUtB3xVjM74wieTaQPJAYhHS1yqLZ5WjOS7yCiQFlbhLBynwEWY5gZTkqewiyAoGcBwxcxSAk37Ei59pJxMUAYh9vfRIG32syJ/flbFyur68XcY9nIHAqcXZ@0Zdz8Swk5qgX4pMxHC2PCITXJ2sEyHPZwDgSQLESzwEKnnV8MmKc61SEn2kwz5X63MHpt6a8eOc0vMGHkuPrFVX7ooj1RU7lm9ItBm7LtUUgvuLKohddjcM4Sy8jm4OOQF0ScuupeGgqwV90JgYtoF95alQMHI4gCBQDRAQPj5ZgV4@Ndc1vH@wQuEMGPl7nBJMTrAjTEJAoIDGKkBhECNFA6zZafcuHg6G4GOM7vvkARpkc4Ioznh@AdkK138uJxBgnH65wAz7xoikaQzh9o5Cgsb@3gY8328e4Y3bv4Dk04QLWI8HGv141FzlGv4qbisFffqG5GhQBZBuf0Ii68qaazB8DvfwFNg@5gJ/GzhNS7RCC8cRCOyS@0NyGZgpsnJQeH6ku0ZHexeQDFGNlmGewW5UpOpJjxN8hW@SvbKJDb5SaSAUOP6EoIFIIaXZ6XDs42Tk8fkWUO2rU9o92a4gZJpgtxW4zeqkIdhDDUHU@qPr0DOHwCxKa10lpem/A4C9NRlj@djpOPABsUEyDQqdLhPXlTD8Dz4PnJSCJ4kODUtFoq9Yc3Lh31QcTlXHmIOStyEsthkJRpnkjIQ14syOhJ0erKOmIlqbqGBEXGJtesqIYXJ6kPXwbMMukN9RRz0U9qkv8YvNXcuWy9J5e5CNnYOHqsNqWguRXWi3VoRP6Y@oDSlXvUCZCsgQIBSHzaz@WH/xsij/2Chz0mkIadDO@3jtWcyeVRdAeOe1@ko4bUJA4Fk9HuvPUSlKLRM78tcETqqM2qTI@lBnP7YrndgW5cYHLrqYVMq1@cTWhiM0jj@aR54rrxp5mxtUTfys5tVwHOr3Tw5tvyBbCpQ41GDYT3fpgjiZk3ROvyZ54vXjcE@crd48rZYKwkxqZGHDG46eYMLfbQLbojG2DTq7Q7GtgY/tzj6HeoodGSn7QyZtiEDxxSgPUaQ/OE594hupBzkBMIA3ptMyFyK5Og4qPLyoQsqRXnlhA16BTmMIqoBkgLcaH00RdSZU0HTFRDASiWBWjsN32OjlBjgczuz19oAuBMJQfOByfSuDH@HhGRXTSKw4rhBo5ZKyzUgTXVZNJSBDjdg3SaUDcYh2oeJo7vxrF2WqIynk6mcZPwKCoE26ZiwIE/QzzHgj1Mi/PrXegHt5hOEwcC1QsUxYnKLwTvWdHLCfncoHjv4fnB6xQGJ8Oxpuy2Eo2Mz5yjHdmsUIp9JPsZGN7AudH7DiiQZGtkGdw6g66oKrr0In5o63h0I9l49PiIX@Myr5ytcxnsI4Qx2JocFgfX57eVPEl4bhe6zJ5KKdCCyAUTwOvn/cGbwDsDhRbMVyVn7FEQS5WdjFDSog6rGo7/NX09HJ2kPj47nAYFmyVG4AhpG22aJMk4qB00NKDPu1GSqDCcKPaeA2A5oqD/gskcwQ7cNFQ5UzgBXrCoerxBiehEAnUo9HIwslIwzJSj5tehCtL6srpfoZKebov05DmvcgVC0DkFaxCNObu0IIg8MwwQ/PxZfE2K69L@sBj0T/PNDg7yPDJqTcPF2j4GDM789fqc4wxxF2t4Bg0FJuYCBXVqR7zzsCRBPCOQLU8OwQHosewTsMT4eKzUaQgvtpd47ZwRjKCtAgapWhIsZHrcJeOuFCNohf8V1kTP1eg98XEzoCRODDnH48UEMjyMQ4hzkZOQ2D/5BDDIA4oBe@oy@nx/oMh4vDPu6H4Jg7xZuHojol5ASLg81pSu3j5@Zm0@bUQfZQy5UfSpktKUbFAX54PxqsswLB2ATAoFMkjr1Ie2NnR@NybB0ilJ4PUY4WfyO1rCy@ymwGaoMRXFt0nxL2w1c1DCon75o3KF6nEthqhZgbahytJ0IiCEYhnqd8LU4WggScVeOmagRRcZ/bSeJKEYsSh31mRI6B8x3LWOw7sCXTfzDk@1zuvopyTvap61aQWpNdJ65pFQ@NkXUW3CNY1Kc9WdjVQWe@U8URlRSKvnrP3Oxjg6OjmLb9/AQcUSZxclr5rJ9h3bVwMESHBMcqjxjz5N3nWOdAhv6@Me6RfP7@sdGjW9/C@KtYOUbQH@R3TId6M18nxfcI0BMgIbhplb3M9T7WwINQZUHom0mVjwuzss7OHotMBeU1b9fFu1P2sh2nMMYSlwn7geGgI@qTaE8Ae2GeS81iAmA@L71QPwga4SEjmiU7qcQdGxONiPKtMWIPHB6gfZMQgFiE7A0eUH01PMmW2FCOM48PkfBxeEjHcj/t/OViQ0YMFQXLQGpEY6/w1I34lwv1vujI61t0sobmB3mVl4eejUMSE/pbPeHpA1BrrC/7sgM8HgrqBULQ9ZRANW6DAw9yYH41OMMj9QfjxDSMf@QIfHs2DlHQDSDAZXTURFEi8hNnAtMgKTGJmi0mtQxS1eJtMlpsakgwhPnZejSfWBSJLZ5O4DMidcXmmVhPoGB1yJmtcmV/@Qaos3mpN89Tg7R/Y8MtYeVyyHM@zLDwc7O12IBRa39JVfnJH3m/UDvf8q62YeAG76pgY5KRMu5u@1a61NAcMnYhrq5LqAPs5XlLFYxrbZzCU4YVTboqdqHyzAuq9qJZ9oOmkOoh9wER4A5YBwJ0OaLxGS8U3ari3uH9AIHBSwcJCtOKAHm4abGSazXHpFXEyhxcgQWV3oPBdIMygSW@Lbymuo47UNCZMN3X46St4Q3EapuRprGH60FD3IfUJdAk1daXcKKGtQMHo5PRUrnQHXSiJtiOKcfH907R7BG0ILr2DvWlC2/j7U8UkgS5bNA19xAy8AqCr4IvQGb0SF7JCzruFatKOW7GoQ1seVJpHrGRKBRL2jhjhKB2O36kUxOVjIf7u1DU83@GYyC62SntTKfnEnpapPRm8Y05uouDz/MmwFl7O9eV9Gv4Wj3Q6kNY0vmbfx7w9HnT/F5D9oZ0f6TSaRy1dGTHpVqG7odnmymqmsIZzLa1rEBtib8FLdAIauzq08A2kuDEAx3Evra7eqDrLYTO@0ZwBAJ64A6hSKGzZSreveIDR3BrDbAJ3dNH8euJE/zjKNPXJkA6em2DjGTWeTGNMHmOjE1xiVEFiimAxLqgxkFrw8xS3PJumxdbA0Vabgy4NBnguy0uBp6OURBMTKLFqtBl7Cs81eELRsUjL0I@x81f8@6twP5GpsQvo5nXmLVBI5RDVArp@hZe@7KXHkQPBAis6MGDzVQ0YEZZZQ0xGuZUAoHEMi3I4h9s9afHcA2mbe4dotaEM@eZiLwaraImbHh/cU7LMAntKQCTgfVPImHQFVjrtWUYiNXyXrOfZiPBYshpFuXtsIuKj3rJPDm//QofvPlmnO8EYXeJJ5IyVvV31cpnde4C4BwQ1HNxZkox4OwdQw7RxbWa8IwVIL3mzsMfQBgqQ@wIkNRyyGY5LgWrwDd51bu0SKsh0tFz31rAgvJIpe9Tgr57223@8mPWEt@YCVXyRXmR9x4Q6LbX4QgytkogFpomy4uAleIS4g@MSQ3yU8wMFTHKDsCaS0TThG1R5QbnNFYQF6pxJGlISbMi6aH3n06cEGwkvXooe4vceZxKjilz2L0pWjUH/DicjCZ5kYCUQ@J6pIO3LIfwVMzqbZ@73bhglSKyjIA@RoMCgCy8cTRt3mQST78uUc4veL8VFPOgRs7w/dy/WpYH41i5gKkL/dT5MrH3XlhI8P1wyIIfsObL1xDg3TkS/1MOReR0dJkYgOhieR6qKWQe6hXGevKNAFN1RItZphIBBO2xDwXXHBtIu6t1AxhrDCkyQGqMK2vD4/V@o8PJuQRfIIPwaA8BkEgFhhso8ZZfiicwg@obxOMbDpG4yfmCt4SzbSz8Tj61H@Hn6IP778SV5RIfGMNEYxbx9KZCiMVomEvjbU@5nqkvF@w3qO1PeqfrO0MOv7wP08Os7S8@fVF/fYvyWKgJDDD1wjoNT9qcwo8ZX13uB3E7xlGFgZjxCbb2bTj2w8DU2U6npZQWzqU3LMh28rnl@CXiecwpB8YFwyPMpz2MN3DBBTnPzkVzMQNfDC@idEO/iton6YpTc@LJAPn6BPqlz27YYoykAMZfIou97k1N@yCAmhpJgkCcS/fphVlymcnUC1LZr2l9cYYGsyn7BqaJ8DsYosV/7GOPeAI5A1Wn7IpTGS4KEirF5SQaod2C66SQYNj@JoLqQj5OpkOpsbiqvETG12F3paUIkdqQ9Pksaa91SYK2pQdIZ2DWgT/jzWN/eO4x7DM4bgyy9kbg3SsNUbK9D1rZNvhGbHQnrFB57AhXe7dnmoNtjeFEU6oAIy7eUd0zU7lG7BK0e3xA5wLtq1rxtcdFx9X37cZqdWQwm@XR@HnvuqyO2iYp/c4S2ZG4LiAaGCbHDamHB050WxibtBZL0PnCdG/q4xWGcPbVZoABbyA9QhFdoiYPsj4md5mTsDWJJ2ddAJMV11b7lomat8Spg9cfJLFyGGSdEDcC744uUlQUfdH5hORsHSkulCxZ3H1hlXmkzcwtJx1CnC9lU0dSXeaRw3Io4bbuB4mDuWJot9XfQfn6ufPUa5v1fYE3I1OPKBMGpMMnFzdGg7ODRvD7ePo43a3BOhRk4oDwwbZwbjhJzMd@iPY56l3ILcy@aKiNcPCWK04P57A1uNJqbmlbcego0FR0dQERQAlKt@NoZrpfhK8Mw9SuajvqJ@QTYIVUO753lxTBbuMrsJZ6lhG22VLXtoMqqIK9QOaN4vEF0V2@VsK0pXZwhwkzdE71eccgeTbPFntbipzI2j7AotvpxoNl8so2lSUFb0r4fYIXNntq6Jlh8j84Ye1IzkkA2w02aHeZ8HCg2mhxMm8UjTkjIeD7SHIudONN6lBBQ5Qlg4rzKrBISAEb1E6@CnGIrz16HphpP5tFmHXynRMQR74sQNiOkbdD2g1aTFAN55RtkYHjWxQldzSE8gel3gnUGOspi00phHErCycoGfahYNhcr/BLDiWoGPBNAXLBOxgYwim0oto8hSsO4GIm5pPkyeGkGGrN6ADjJof05VoC@PtGAlBN0m1jeoUNBY/sFRJP9PIr85ngwHdxrYatiCoFpMrEEZTKLlobiWayGaSSDmDnYLGKAQ7DY17Zf5f@l9mOoABkoe0DA4PF3tDC2FDRWUtHF7BN6OtUSGVlUBeRAf6C7iqGaA0cf/a4ZIbRAb4IUujMEjcj7Tngn1XGchvHZWRpfBsD20oe03Q33JuBEHYR3dn8NY6RTIWqw4fqmGGeZLo7BOAnvZTK4TBQ9xbh9EYeDo7cnYCoGr0xASw9uE3DpjFeCbxsA0UnHxQw3Rem8DXZKyx2QEO2ZuLkC95QO0B6EezxsPCJGTYICG@uCyE1LtXlmwG0jc8C88Rn4dXzVJwjI8V2bGmQqhj7Cj7IZq4V8zwcSwIO4A6hwy2FXDaQB8QsFB3CyHUG5veGtqQobBQ5ufHUL3/OIOVC28ETcGj8DN87wJ@fGV@HQ5otZIu6pdBm8VgA6W8BKxvfZRxfF/D7mTfSn9j@RyuzZujxYzlBibz@uJNCuilmznDeB1cq00SKqVXCnxjqesIB@CaAXWn2xgmstfNcG2c6wFW@BQVTFbvWgStBeGjKMaxOd2lqbyAZzODR7@1eZOwzQVzBXrkAbg34Tr6TpEL38Y5q07oFGcgCJjlHHKOfx0UuNJJwWB36@xK2eZD9ux/y@xbOieQlOfgDQtyPhCCrKRPZLQRj0j3c2@dTpRIUXTSFZJAv6L0QgXlMi7qOficrWvZvr/SlftjyNUX4EY2xsPJs6EoYGLzewxenWtK/5yhGa3Ujyu4pGdu//p71nW24jue5Z@IrWULsYEHdeJIrgcCmJ1C4TSWRIymsXxMXiMiBHAgEYMxCBpbAV555KKlWON3bs2E7lYieVvCYpO65KHvK@/gd/gf/AOZfunp7BDElp1@tKaqkSCXSfPn073X1O97ngWyArLGMhdaOHj/x@mMcvGepyLgxrQusZD5bTZnD1Ja@ipgA2xR4b9LDhVDjA/IZXC5WWtTZyhWkLtrA230CVZRZqRnFZfrnkjV0Tj3pz5TtEtg2qmKZbcqwdcynwXMurTLZrG/W6kruK0IaElBSB0KrleP0uryRVHUVCQ1DceJZxqPF5R4HVpLlT0UyZofjP7VTDJ2nF7W9W1Gpk@nAcpo6wDq0k3DZUdReVeQPrk0WGn2KyOjqAw5uNG@0YfJ1aExOp30WWVhPW8LoRk78F97iOLOmNG9PXGR0aC60mHt7JW0TNchmQ3KGVAZeYNmJSntoYu7z0E0xVpJInhzuA411gMAVpvgFfzctwP8jp53q5QP2g5AdEO8ZJX@TdB@g7ad01e/5AujKjg5UL@fRe@HovMWoFcvVy3bXGXWwKvvRDmdBAZd465WZXbzmkmssP/jxSBE56h2PEwes/Z2gLKof6bLUCUGSyIl/4ZcG6uhNH9FKNuivvyLgHYrEhq5V9UC6MsBP04G24syGp6t2RewJ/DjxsUcfPIr@kX75LmW2@TNzf231ytHPQONj5ys7B4Q6VJEV@bVA8Hpbppsw/R@fefYk360cc4mTeH3lwjuOJQ3GWUAI/bA@CQDwEcdcFcfxFE0o2x24m9c196VF63lPfHa1z@SNm5sn4njSNfQ9NhMaoqgT9O2cBnJ@HbT/HxA9nIDmkQq3XHnoy4LhQGdwzYTPnHNw/cSW1BhScliCkZQMeKYNucI4coJQmom/McNL0OrCa3ZLUsVXQeOUQ@kvQDhGQAYB81Lqdlij@tblWYeBd4DmRjcS2cphbkL0fVMQ@V7tN1Ypt7hfykM3eoH@Skd4TjBYQ5waHVgGja6@rISajIKgC9RbQUyCONPeIO1RG@aBcLVXKn59Lg/AR@zfkreANTPLf0M573k4/MX5Sktm@igFg8DizmA1dJGxSogVdcrSmqEFdrKIlWdGbmZOnW5NL9Mu/YQvyFANy2bqVL8Zo/PO15762mfVn9rHwxZvhJBJwxCpHkW@iiuns8zPY@b9iNfJ65iJXWVF8aTqRbDohA6q9jvFEdjFL2sfIeezu8YU9XjXp6x9faXfLcEYxnkztWhFFWx3BJqo0H8ajkZrI11Oij2jQR9TKf23q8Ol9TbAFCLubrHb8Gr02jCMiHa28lia8DtRzhYq7qa0/i7Rf1Wuq7aNK@2iKvGd4kYZrTjY3qiJNu82rVyKiBs6WLqzjS@QvNcy1eYtyKm9cxilldHl2qDszLhlTf@dLwYTSOshbIGNkcXitaIg5Sa2mTaKEq9QiCvFSjsopXLP58YuprYcjGF6WkhMx8xJfttVexLHBQFR0NqDtQS4@RxGU4WVsGsro1Ki5SKtMLrQ5mxD9Av//xdpKkyAbeHxpZPUbNLL60mrkS6uRL61GLrMaWbhZHvujcsvrl4E164niOXD/mQVYUNt74v337h2Jo/d2xMOnD35bfG3vqXj/3hNI2RP7T@8/2n0g4P/Ok8MdQQX0z1fcEarcC5j6bbft0u38UqWyIgjzXIDyFXHYPBPvDdruSyCeDb95tnXKX0p9N9jkUjsv3dF0wM9BQ1RmCaTVBN0V8VuTunFCi@sWUPIZviMqX57YRvLm6fPNEtleUDh0bcDNb3vEg5AeFz0raaMNgB9AKqBp8pMs6U7j0zoxLZ2SkAOnf157BIEpfHwo7j3Zxkif27tHu3tPDsXDvQP4uv81dLMjtnfRbcz9p5hFgI/3tncf7j64RwncgEpJ4N0aGaxf1oQSgtOotF90xxgerIdSofwW8eq9kMn0B8oqwhfZcT9039MBksJ3d3Z2WiMX7fatewfvfgW5GvfrwrIwyKXhUF1aINyqoNEI1CajaNfYmTqylsUqb0hnU3ELs2sZugOizwWhkOfondhzhfUArxHxQZriZjPDplBDRTcBN6JSjmAdQREYstnCBqHchNro9kDVhherXfUFi25Jx6woRy4oL60@IcXgjLv9NofRVQlA96zVTdUGIwbACyGZwAB4B4MJQfOFu4uXJGJVQowDFPwh4TYnPD8bPjxHrhENXGXCfQ4EsibbxPNGU4oBjppen@cxYtbEuwPFSKEiPsGjk5xeT125kkoc8P/yjQ1fZQHSgl2wCytbCRXhsxtQA@ztp81u4AvbyeFtMIggbt9jTa2TXhPEPboXHqHB0ktUI6Bq1xz82VSO6hXDSYE4lQjTmopoO3S5bXnwu9ctByXvz9WIenvUaVSYkvGfrmzA/bkGvAkaQFQ09wt0KzQMiLElNIOuJGXbHwBFgsgnPo5GNRp0xm03UkDKOvZz76OPcnKQC2ERQ8WHWqc17DDUAz6EnKMPKnJzAUIMaUqe4msUz6Ed7UH4NnyGyhAjbOCHanBlbabwoGqUmjiyUuTnU2ptNckY7spaieJZN1hvX0PtM4qev302y6NnkhaKyVqa89GfMyoxoGenEbp56QpULJoG1BIO7pAJ946PhV@uf7DmbG7ff1b8@MPCcbl8wttCs8OPF6yUyM8sJJLD8tC6k6QNqFaaRJrxxy0srfQZebfEVa6QAeNy6gHzvdWo6Ty@Vp1P71O8rGg6Jb565XCpItmbEAlhJJlwdyuIuqqyQGWORU4iCPdOaCx61lUpBcKp9@stjGuPs1CDEenjPkLqNWZYNdKvMbxd44Me7CwZyafxdGv8ORWLXFIU/djmfJQ/sO87@c1cWUHRYtLDaastuqAwV3OyVzOcXjqv5tBtX44O9u/ro1u7tHV8PLwWtu1Lsb1W24r5dFx8LBm4ro/240vQ8uH2Rmih74V0xHxIzmPTlK6Js3BrQdH8FTV@ODd3tPYADZ69GFFVIzVqG/d76CHO5ktxaBoVyJloQobo8Gh75@BAWDt4y7YOZWHfa/bbZF@K2yDivqk8HbEdMm12Jc006TBBmnlSKTM2L41We9liThy8lK1C8iAFOR56s9BRe0EymUjrCD5ZiIVAw2veENXIRVt3ofYgvy4Rz@qoCSXCSTM6mEns5gIfPuxknzaZcNwKzBv7L7yhZmbciXTWRVfVo6mJSDHCeBw0T/DlO3n@3mf@eF3VwwyW@/UxdRiV8NvoL18cQsVDfCkuRWfwkmlRU0o6K0SlC2rsyCwvymF/doLSsdhnkhc2tnXJHMumMX98y4hkR/zpFr7zT2Vm@0zed6otnlI2zAnNhYeeHT2CgMkEMVhsmVQBxY9n8gij0dDnpKMZcnOt3aLW1FUrKZqZxF1LB3oLOPjV2/HtIV4V7LaXVlX8fKriUyJSkxF3a74GlQmYb6@uLl@FO94LVbz4WXHzGRLfP4Oz4cumgdKf@qQqBJS7@6Sg8kMCuGToHJACO7ZaMLGCwOoknCmRvtNhZLYP2nI@Qls8aMze06MC3hfFa82JSaxtydj5RDKxE8hcH4wlrDvKq2Zu9GeXV3efgrpdUd/N16@PFxsC4X347FccJvNgMMStEhjxUYO9ooJIvu6jVlyAJTj4oPb0a8TA3FJxLOscb26LX7jRRppr3AoGL1CvX0XOlLHNLHyGKp01hxev8ILrFV2Zch7aBMiyXkFsPWcdFY6sudUZkBJBV4ey3OJWRtNgm3/ZMINvrqP6IOUxgPGA6egBzL6dFSD3rOOtggo1mc1zGvAnOqnISUCrAcoeOn2R09EuwRv2pjq9zOkdFwPP6dQNieW8qSNeZjclZDxCZtaSwHRX63WnDRp2nf0OZwMbo5Peko0B2bI30Kk3ORV1qlRSXZYdh0nHnASSlE5akFB4MHmBSUu@675o0CTLaHOAMFsQfa93XJL6U@/YUnbMSROOgCcSyrv9ToYmhWKealTqSNhC17KShOpb3nGJFCjlBoQyWTixvJC2vLCACQzpRuhLJiouRg3A37IRsqkm8WLN9a3nSOEj12@PXbEzQRlfxUZUVEmOQRbEzpNtsfdQHOzt70RRY4sbyKNQKaWwR6GYZcOoO2rJFmDCB@PgtMGJ6ms899zlXIWCv2ug/mBkAPHXeK6qgFAc47IUF686r0QdDu@hnhS7kzuWk656rPtQag/G/eDi1eQVTe8EOL0SkMA7YlbCS4J35oZFrkTJYStyoLc4DAuJfGVDuVUIa6EUqmUifXMMpMV1bM3nZhJbRu@fMHWwMmmTDgNywjaJO8EAWZ51Gd8ShqN9GgbcpLdsR9h2vGF4KJVKc8l5cUcHbnTNiLvRyq5ZST6tkrthJUxhGk/JxziiYW050RmIV94rVVl4qODRvxaXdvRoo@9mOY3GEUPLLgJTOTay@VXC6HMnE/00t@DkDIpovFH5usELAoO8h7u5wzQeASP6ngPTm4MC4wU0B0erIALIy2QOkMrPY2wktzJceglFklscrsf55qTUEqJLKJJcS9jo6FSEaz02G@0BcGcckAQ/NEAQNM7XxJkDspmrOG2xinhBSYokzjS4Tpv/5BLqUNs0QwA9HquP1WM2vRFZs9il8NERMVsgO28MCO5B5E4FjzUzvRpPN48ksWkUj0MYjYoBA87YSXX1XLAnkUjSOVpq8bIioy0ZDRx5LXk0wpZzbIASCaWAFqOgvGpCWABFEOLi8GQxQHklRkHzyaAG8RO8iTXWVmM1atB8MqixPuawFpOwRkHzcdC5fY02yujYa4Z20b588nIpfKyJzqjKnbjtccAnjXJaAWsogOVhMloSuuOdeME7ImS06FMJ2oNEu7ImPWKrNBDwV@9o1ocKKFbbbIKsNkSIu4XBS3kJFfN1lMm@hYy5Zh4j8BziGt/HDdA6QZjTINgDk2yIYjKkQKNOMcWKmUPDpSaBqJExkrDEwgV8nSH3W1@4YHGHI79bBSs3s7hZtcguCn1SyVI@2thQY1EKBg1PJP7UZOMJx2AoojhKYdIlPxEc40Cn4hVHoTdo82VnAXHVlLBWh3QUwOlhJ4YDX1Pm@6IKAprjq9uBDyrzOLAJeXFZp0wcSqiax7F4bRxKYJvHUbx@O0ieSurLW9fGwYJgEo7ytXEgBc6PqbVwAQhm/NtKIrXIeKBZlExtFlpR0tA4m5FvrXhflKgq0F6QMETgJ7FvSe2QjLlJ6z1DDLrWeKDQMT8etscraROOYtq5K3zBXMWSubn1wsItpfINrLHyauKWH3TgICh1e3p9Jyz@mIgeuySRCOneA4WYUvt0BCISzmZJSh@KASGc0P5GA1WzGg26Gdo/2Hv34N7jxpN7j1GIWuA9Cq9vUFuG1HUqpSWMZ8@3LQ3SKXIEqlpgNzK0Dxt51D6JZodOEYoci6UWLgy4mcUMFNbk0H1Rqe@ei4eQRUHr53AiZEnfzcD02NQGvalbxZdWLoQ0TzDVKymvbUJLCIbpRLaEYIzkjCFscflnfdZQedZ/FjBgS9TZJtM/Ntv7DA2XjIJCFF8@C77ijlqoS1LUTkt5FlEFH2U3ck6FKhfyBj3EYEzgr8plcV85xZX2a81eG13ejrvk@PbM6zXPWp1maXg6zHR9R7qnsbNdH51cZlCZavdo5@CwsY9xunYekOUE/tQo72j38c7e0yPMOYSsZZm8c3Cwd9AgBfWDp/tH6DE0lmSZgBJLCCYTIkBP9t6798iA4e@WbCQbhPggb8If6cqnILxhY0K/p2TmUWBViAYF4SEzFSxKaQUReGfuYKyCt6H/CXXAF9DyBB9loC4V1Zgc0th4/SnzQl@nMwOK2jEaDwMCJQ14OzYSuWgJhjnzT7AA@SLygW8nbfoS3yhjHhryDYZ2rCwayGCxjLTv6vq0OnCZHE77bVuhk448CxduHyDxtSk7DrrFtewsh14lh6Q0FC@cLcPJUSbnqNnkknIEpVZ6xghiZF671jLK4B2gyKKEJiG0TKEC/IJYE/m8l7vImAGiZBbsqhw/6kIYNvRRGBm/5oYxR@zWlPV8oX4kEP1JWuBoGuGv@@ajFBGYfJ8iY446Wp7rMaO/qrN8w2zr2bHpfSq06y6h9sgDaPC9wGZHL@SzL6Q7@dwlG9DAjPiMR/MAvXwbkx2mCpnG/aAGAxWMpoItCP1ADxf0/Bh/T6Rr1zYq0NhAcDkT1rI4l91RopGQHzAAiXnWprUeurFhswStOMwQGyZENQniAxNiKQnipQmxnATx6ScM4nXtfF5N3qZYWl1lbebIfCYU/zddvFhUsBtKFTosDPjM4uo0ZiQ7jENC5x00BzXPbEButuz2pS2Lov703wG3iUuWKlIl3PBLmn0J5p//nrXON3TXGKW/5h4aGxQyJ/LJi02Y8b7wgSRx1SRpSxrH9pNLsFmWmsXkst8NKeKDFKL59KcRmGSy@baad6HHT71w3QjLVkOrhjiC/5hH4LwOggaXV@uLvI2yAS9mL61rLKoHIQIGWTZBluIgSVW@urTKiomvmlhl1QSpXKfKT38m65TnVwLEDzUE7bVyMBNB/yuy0Eg1HwolgfoMiTY1@@Grbyr4SbQNZrEk8P0QOxU5vrzdP/9GvN1hyUT4308kTipg0pea9sSB/4fr4lhOxfEhoygWU8ctyxD5fCrEpz8K28HDG19mly2Sn//h1aUr6aV/NywdHvOb6uBmrkEhi2@BWj0omklF6xobzx8MgE5JaI1xjOo1Zyw5PIulwVi0A1WdLS3OotlLKnuamL2ss2PIZ8xgKS4J/esRY7TBEQaJNQo/k5UvM1wqc9MxubYcd8jkdplZlwbmMDaax5GmOAbTsxkTOBYjQsY8apmbk8zeLENccC1R@PGbo@Zpv4kBWv1BvyQjgHiD8s7Z4LmHB9WojG4uSs/9NGnos7DWhIDkOAfF13uoUAFNlU5FWPeb5XYEbLbb47NxD9/QHClXoWOkchldxpEg2B@f@RInnrj3x14PeuAgpxayiCDmDaGVdAoDK32t6mNVJ1U7X2W5zHrjJXJDR0nUtvbIGwZUmTMvC6DLJ2JQoQpvw4BVLDwaqF8QInZF68j@PPL6rm3AYxRXr2AkkF@EvMOlakQZ8TExcBRQA@TJ@CyC4ULOOOnGOJxT8tHix64UlnDkXKQbMXIxQoi2jvB8sSR90JFrGUQiLYhGUSxLhZUcjxIh2gfyPItCrBSWKljRELPIRRF5htaa5c0uuS0io1bCQdg0NM0CcIQhejmumxXoHWTodjnWL//2k7@zchflskqjmDpevwkyA0UkCbHi16PBvvpuoEf5RNoqxnD/fYibUXfctnfWxAg1gYEaiCsFM0wgYr4AQkOnVYMe7DeDE9vwBaMqRMIql@9tb4uj9w723kdrKL5EICqIFUciWBdWnoedSkbypWIwgkhKmId5LCtGINWIeSjdKwTTPSb3Ol3b0MCC0frmH9No0V3@ADXdeV3GEGK2xU598J4QdWtNtHoiFAXjPHzzjxjzYMjas8mIB0NLEiZ8HLpA/Ooq0p7rF0Mk1/eL7/8ZVSctSoDnw3uVM7PqNKafcuvyQpZotlg9Tu1VpBoahFTEVw7Rt35MyHwO0q02wswNc1fUSJK7/cO/EoQDHx9g9oySIoInfyWibzMi/XpAI5eKr3glvu8wvo5HrwAmotY02sXHcE6WRmg0ZBvJ5SuG7xffly0GeC/AN5NL6liMNDeTOBn/as4slZXTkTa/Bv7UGf6BiVSauaZh5IMqEc8nPwuXqdlNdp3M9H3DWJ2xpiV2@JP/TKI@0jGH1YMewBmtOVWJayWlzX/xlxr/JHNjcgXB/PJvv/ejsI@T1J5NUvvzvXA1TeZ7MUlr@43YlvRVPDKs/CR1Kn4arSaycieO8TUNwU/Sxn0SHexJ2pIH0teLfnLFsk9D8m2FRC/4yZVLPg3XdxSuxMUe71bKcp@kLnOFPWWhx/AvpjQTFuO/mItxctnMp675dLL4G0KODB8aj85NS7ksOZwKsbYbokp/0TMv/t2Mt8bc/fCqLWRcHOCoAB1KTRHaQ6jJhrnyL@Ix5WfM14SpVelsQfXIqKUqawHRpNnzE6pynM@triUcOhD3EmrZfLNKMrNyue@y0f142EGpg97vzkjyGNHzHwYPSN4Zv0FzCdw2iCtsbUPuCerU5GN6wfHnyAfRkc8hJWqgB@gOiBv0d0N3t1jlFJI3bsSx9AbMEt2g63QUhVIFESlJ5KvHiUIFy6mJC@Gf9A7E0lWLpSscLNlH8iMb5ly5eX/rR3pH0qM0iGKPocxfjfMf5TSQihG9lZPHDsnTpaN2It@0IBVNVUdA6tH9z@ZuEasunZc0wNIwf/dP9EHn@qjL2oH@oMkrefzH4Jg4MKknoLF/8kdCYOcWwy0jteY/VRPv8w6VVjmeZNeoJ6WaH/@BhaSdPEicXbtayJIYU2UssftEPD3cORB7T4/2nx7hhYzpGFHL4OmCHovdvC@TABu9JJiTZWsg5i@xOGvkMXl5BS@/lKPu//n3sPuMNu9YFcsYpkvL/SBSrqrKXTJGNBXXHiE5PnPl@dICWsd1y946zpocIRCgd/sBrlffhQ8SjC8m2OGzPNuY/Nlk2pS6ZcWM5xpT/3l2y7iMSb9MwKMOJ8CpCpw/p/IlZXwxlEFXVlN8vXOSXvMYP/RCufwk0C@agiI3m8kXvufn56Uuhqcaj7yS66N7Ih8dw5WHJ8As9Ad0qYlus4HwvDbItui8cNx@EX4qtpv9l00fFWTemaBKtHP37Sn/zaTdEQ9PzjgUx5veEwtBt72FaaFdAGSFVvtFoXveqckMNgzWCieciNzPSH0589Unb9jVEIMA79l1Vqv3oj3oEbdrtXpwkFlh1dxDBTlVX@X3oceGMeoSeSq9nwpimm1WpBD4aEA58BG4KmVd7E3q0@NI8YkuHtFm8Tki5qVIWSEY81mPg8IGTDh/Elaqqq1PpLN4bUKGrw@oFKIgEc1UwUQswjFnwkrxm/hChWkIOY2koeVP26HSarz5G8yjowgDaGIIA@7a5foHz@rPjvu@e754nC@fFNDREUK3pFkjjSn57OHPOPq9l73hwI8k9V0/YAWXikpqn0pqYFphxRc5VjGNG2iWVrjxwkFD7UCHMnGLvhfYnjRTJW2cU3retupWOMbcsLpsDI60p5QMZBo@PBmm9iaiYwMRpusuqUh8SbpQ1vsj9KelYIsw5ugApj9FM0IM1BBdKjKGqZhFW4WvZZwAw84@cGNdUfkwFfVYltHNmZx/s/k3X7v5XVgXya0nguVNMaY0NnFhw3XlcmGPmJuOMa/QgvJis4cu/6ydPrmnUYqDudpiWZmmcD3YBRl01pj8tnQ8wS@pfamFgnVNUfYVU4eXJa8LNaRa0yR8had8RQiyPG8gHEEkoZgri03MYiDp8sZBz2JJxc6NRk6okRMuwtCTlEYey2IYyNN023CMTtuacB4Bvipr9JJYKPzmS4xPxa6IFsu6znDPISpQFoYwoUhn7ePE2utGo41NK4YACXEOQcftNse9YD0T3/CqRf1N71E8lGqP4m@SDHivAAKjLbjGSmW2JjL5YoFX6R65vYRP9YxVLVQKVfpX4f9WQSWq/9X5xEoUshpNrBRi/34ticc4ssliUbWyghty5lcLYjgNTgf9pcyC0Ge2oDMb/RHyC@pzn9@H/b43HLoBhTkSJ24fH7cx8Ks3wBsLdP6FcXXg8wuX/IusK@SCn2Ibz/0GImpIRKXhVFi3tiwY97PhYBSIj3peS33GGOW3V9Q3f@qjGynfdYkH8oEJks/cqO97NJruBnt9vJcoo8fkYMCfW71Bq3wGorw7IleOPqx5gPAGpdG4XyZ3U26/g8/iZIbQfAFNO4XqoGudBoA1sFt2DinPd9E9pfVs0u1a5LzF7XUOXWTc8PZI6Egqux3iO5r@qYXb2oJ4AkzYOrtbUT5MtJcuGnFXZOVjXLHH8ZxJYyBrRPpCjXeMZUmaGRYqRcv3enL9Z5XoARpKWTliy@wcnYiDIIRXqpyyACuGREpgHzFIHzPGeFaEPcIQoS5alshG5IWQCdSO8KusNEygiuT57BWAPcReKSta14ZpZZ6xuo7uPfGuzKnm9E7hoZ1UdW0dY3NQT3BAcZrk03B1DXPIQaUvMOIc@6Yx@5F3ZEsAkCeEAiECjz1Cjwyt56REipd1cHgg/ZVUHl5PtNAlWo9ivOD9Vd89oSgp4rzlcSiYjucTAJYsn3zkDeUQFSKk2hqfAKtNa4Eiq3i@P3ZX76ytUIMorpEC7QzaEdClMmBG17JlatxpcNbTvbgbnIqe@9Ltsf83bjbFfuFFSXRmy@0Tr5tv54h0YCgjPYVRsO8WOG175@Gje0c72wVRrK4iOBuoaljbGFzOzlM@GXBIMsIivHxLrdsrTOS2X8hulbM52fQtc9jzZoMVAtizRijHDe2sQ8XkzRwjBpGpg3tVQcdb1LHdUFcblxs2ZTzCqAWWGly18hcWLCRprGsBSTCyOUKZXHhowDfYeOaAUvcKGAG5uzVQCMNQQkS51sbNYlGvqXX6VISNtVjcZDtz6wHI4S9E9mDcj@y2WVo7TZGFTQ695fHWdjNL@0LJqolTJ/uWn60hd645p5f2OHehQvz1u9gKmwfuaHB/qubPHiutFRiQXL16nMvJhOz//DeIfbPQLKBnB7kL5K8/cpRL2BJv6jvsQdPO8m0wFPuoFLiT4AFtroET1HSB1qAzLVFI0s4DOHs79kdmHUM7d0HazW3HWc5dQJWjIdqhDGEzdI8AY66Gad1IWihyPHvWR7e4iyh/ffXxo/dgyg/Qv5Qf1D84XrxVLmSzcMSTBpKDkT7E9t7jfbxJGOVKdKPwcDQ4k@MyaupKSviwj5bD1PqChV0r4yqEnfPEDWTv/fvTo@bJk@YZSMxNGILoBU7T1PrBMPeoy2@OkWNFJ9fKXZw4BHU6crs15oRmvvPSPsnVAvhzalaxClU4S0uEPYBCDjoQiI2614fT@r2jx4@c7EZTIFYnYVVk8y1NHEAoRDA2JpFAGyEdDKeLVBWw3SYRDPzks9ZmtC8b5eZmtjabpbbn0aDZYY9f2ZCAO/a4IClu5MxPaW0UUsF06DqYwEfbuztHVgHKouyLiRTjaEqbFjsjdlQdTG64U9AROD1EGMdZefttSsMiY99xliqVHKqHzAAb@YAAtLywRrXZqOl0bD2QzaFXoqtzd8J1EXOyVFoqN/v@ObCj5ertyt3lyjuDEb4bdFy//bYPW4jTxJCyXjB9Gw35SZ3sZNDrvt31evhgdXNlcW3Pu/87X717eHvbbrd@C3hI67k/wAf80dBswKh5LrX/YI8dtZm6qBF9wNlulofNF4PySqfSXqusVe903Dur7lplea296i7fbd29e7fdXVlrde7ead5ZbbfK6DaaipTOSHnQYvLHarvXqzaNMVtbqtztdqvV23c6q3e7d5cqy8srrbXVTmVlpbtWbS4v3@4srbXuti7n2sL2ZGCDVfsunh3xHfitdOYuM7e3y9K5/wU';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String os4721en _e25 $91 <>60or 70939597cr=B+Ru8"?!"&&1/<>ca ge
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;b1204=128;y#a= ( +)0b1204;x#a=174;  (!    )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on Ørjan's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153909) and [the work](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43392822#43392822) of Cat Wizard.

New code is on line 183: `b1204 = 128; y#a = (+)0b1204;`.

Without `-XBinaryLiterals` it is parsed as `(+) 0 b1204`, with `-XBinaryLiterals` it is parsed as `(+) 0b1 204`.

Test all ghc answers [on TIO](https://tio.run/##XU/BToNAEL3zFQvl0Ea3YZsqprA9cKqJNjbRYCSETOkWNilL3V2UpvTbEYwHyxwm8@bNmzezBZW3bQoaLdF@mitDViLL06sav69ZBpp/sSeumYSDGtCbChTfVKVmQ@YZMp6uOo9BPwCRvYDutomhJOAC5OnKqW15cSylRq@s1tMVk2xXphiHV@H7ocGF0iBShtZVgQL0nXejaC/L4lFoljGJEhog4jqe6B9iPbTrUW3sQAMKaHCuFou/0YuX0ajXN33ysRUuQytG/13vXKe76U2kvh81sVFT4m3JzJlTMnvwTiOg45uJ89vx6g4Rd@6NzQlV7NMogIvmwDQ6mgl16FFyoW1VFZFj3pPbM07w5QBK28SdLaLKjjCJTdNpMt/6WFpxf8blBw).

Answer (score 5):

## 206. Haskell with ExtendedDefaultRules, 9836 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLfFjF8kiWVKxil1VlEip9eHMeDHr4/GDPZ4djD1rnzPjXew8GNjBYh9seBYLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zzq4XcEmsysqMjMyMjIyMjLxUQ7G7v/51EC92aOqjjm46zFFth7Us7Vq1Emx9xF4omp1NZwIBhKpanUFPNRy7GAgymTHNaGoteGeOeaUa2q1qgX@asb5ldiylx5yu4jDVbip91WbmwOkPHGa250fLMLbVMy@1OMbsaUYHwBzV6luqQ@ErjJ0autJrtJSpkOxUgn0Lwm22qepfel8c1jR7PcVo2QCZY@yNadkqwjdV2zYx@ipjwy21OYU0D6CKpZl71f2XU0EFxl5CFpW@rg6Z0rAdS2k6mmkgTVLseP/0@HAqhiyzdyfb29O@afY6bhpse9C8mg7KsFPLVnRlGv8Kqw4cc9eZ9s@yakc1FJZOFBLp6cAcW7eUmSirzFKVVlvT1QRUCIuzrqr3VYuhD2ubFtuFLOn5VD5Vr45jJpoYNz8OnEZbYHom40yVJ50CwptWVzUgh6npQNkLnApIewEtjRJQrBEL213TAj6y2MBWW@zGtFrAXIY@isQgPhvesoZiq7kVRJDxEFwZ5o0BTOSYULWNkaMywzTiFBkBV5i8V59mrHQWfasHu9P@OZbem/ZbBUZrXrVn6zKdZ0dmfzTtW2BvtL157JxJ8YawYbagNqbCZHaogBclM0n4THqyFTShdqExs0sbMtZSmW1o/b7q8EDgFdWiYIjNdM244g380DJbgyY2PqerQtrYYJEf7EATYlVYX4iJBDpYkDiIg0EOjs2e6s@vzQwVKsjuq02trTU5Y6lDRzVsyLKdYBoU4kbTddZSdYgwxt6MMdvE6h17NXSlm2gmAsiYmArrXelMY81@n/EgKAVkaTuVZypSj91CuN612bDfY7bWg2Cnabbbqspu1X4XogdaZoDB1exPFct7W1IBxlBd0qh9EAhIGhMpDXRyKXRjKUBayxY0cLQeEFZzQjZTFVtDgQpRbNVoEVX7nqg1mTLB8uxagwYPRR9YhNtWLWpyhBeap6UCSsWr5vCNpTkOtRpWZYeqYrETS1Ujk2J3IklIzMQUHCxIgip1bS20dbAdgsrlMRJKHyrTypy8fRVQWKLMluol@JUlqRTY2t9kd0sX6OZSFhigb4WVCCv/wOzkxYUKv6HcSHas@wBgDQBVdJY0@05Sifchg3EHMphU0Imu@HU60dd9CbO1qbrwsRyHakFtgPBh72JUsubAsrAnGRNVuYJC66bRAXpCYa2BgfQwWC4FVdA0oSOIMfUaqAaSl@oI5AJS@KSrQaXZWCW@hsX7QyIo9IjAxoKibrq2qQ8IDmLaDvIyUAWiIsbdNnvH2oqmYxQIR1Q815ZqD3QH4wyMFtY89HdqK8HcbFCDtYCPryE5BZCSB7B@z9cuKVMADBVhUlEx6Md/@metTgfwVJtNkG2CXd@xltmknluhzEJ3yJBhQaDqlC2Ai2HqPDokcK3oWosEhGKMRBKUCUr1xhzoLWZCgtaNBq20q1xDy4bG1XRUzuS8s4@xnnLFpYnGORcK3lMaULGUAKVNxY6zFxtQS001ECSeifcGTjvP4v0tFrKT34efF8PPFy9UyFwkEVleSiY7JWC4xDJ5wVvoMc55V52QlLaj2KbWCvRHTtc00izeZFKzbPZVIxyawBGKhaxGKJJAKReOlLRyM9HWjFY4tAa8WIGEQ5FSs9w814q10lR0f5KA5gbRYHNVw82IFACRQ43iOtkDaZ6AzuFdXLh8YaZdR5JjcMLnjYSZ9rvmHkFSdpAvTWQQkEMJW1fVfjiVkCMoJhBubrkxYF5Jp3CIAhe1WjQUDEX9RScMUNKJgmJjPdFMFFt6v4udFhDFsPvQE1jIu03oqVEy2poDGmeMNYivqRcByUIy8UYNWSp26R4fUZPkTQ7jx1FQCgzjJjTZktWWryGDEIC27Ngz0lg3byBByhN2MyA6DExU6UDVQGRekCovCE@JfCaLxBUNwNZQWT7e0KARYHMDmS543lc2AM@kOQxg443EJ3t6ygiwNHm3Om4wTGtDW@qBeABtqKmizAHho/IOBRMZUPuzQcdGbTsVT2ezk21spok5VrIa/whC@jb5aEvCwvsbEwoa1lZvmK4YnYHSUbkmxpRmU@07QlBBSWwHRNF0f0OecdF5JuxuYOnFdNrUibiqxTgNFPK89kRXqKB0EYp@HNQZlSliqAKaowViSR9Npw4A11OJS58QZCIDn6QHsuBqAMBk6lBtDhyQasDAN12t2QWexdwZXC7yTmg6efDypw6SPd72ksbMyJVn6UAi6XlhNh5EEccancUDnSuiqkx4UOX7PR7HrNi9OYhNL4vQEfh8E0klAbz3FZw90zDnIAVCemgRZDKE1wNoYseoUELH5apd1Fg9LdOrIqgzHAi0kP@6jtO3i9BPaE530EgApyRPrNGuc2AgsyQda6Q5Jnc3dLMBYtmG9pl0U0g2Bw1tOFUg8vPq8NIOXIMC1rZZGXruzwPgunCobYPAJP8NBPYFSSS4CQW/SwBIQAkgVLhtkyjeBqFyPDKaYSlBTSkBjU6KMQkbrgTDHQljeXTZMHsohdgZKQao6cGwTzNwrCBkPol8ZW5X58l@0utCocSlqRnhu9Di4mKoGKqAZF9cfA6uNXQ9R1cUXM/JFScXwiXQRTFi5MLQc4qBfrXQ/bmLeRipYbUNsVe61fph5bxYzNRiyrksnml8RkDUgWQD6Dg@AE8oUi6jMxKRKjdQ0ESjPVn6DZTOx01L6wsivFKuFf4uqJAhMmi9Pg4jLbWEnezjNOmVLegFQWltdsNW6OI8dVG7uLtoRS/uQzGMHSkp5QYUCtIL9xIdyxxAdxk5XynG5Vokcp6BTrJRDqVCy@FwPq5DQkok8l0@ElU4tcMhFaR2@OIiBEQV9Dlvdi3CN4ylIxGPVJAP7JhBJwyHEnd5SL8RqUWiIYgbCcVgiFEOhYAyTSSCTYVGzpwg0MHRa06YjWg0QGxoWlf4mxH74JeAARaPvg38u3E8OeztXYF0ZU1bR1UkbnFtBF6Ty9yzRQ9P4yqyXdJYDehuoQTQ27a8kRGOxo0B6c@k3Jr@hGg4iBDkh30PylVtAgYRt7UhDBCg3Y9cRQj7b9SFNmDAaepq4oxUE4lBw8Fhr5qYqw0d8m4l0bTHPAB6Dzj7utKEhj2J7kJiF4AQ@DyZnB8SKc0gnlaVaFTztTJCx9JUDKRfSyOtfaDZXSQvaFY4lLDaQFVU2UE3UIlqu6wJfX4HKK0ONYfr8MBHxxhlR7HDEdQaq1zrQmUPNQbMlGsDoO7cbMJ4RwXNAUP54JFtGdeaZRpI5MQWoAaGL2EdTCGfR15go2p1N735MH3nIQeKzXjLPtr6sU4Tt2k3WdIwdbNjsmUAQNZMJDhj7xpoKgGdz4HhJbO1WyJQtWMaoykeVLG7t1FHlHMZT/tWEDJJ8IlLkDVsfqHHAA@U@Xj34xb0EHI2lYL8u28purxC@rBMlxE9m2wMIEy2OvIN1uRHtd8dTRiUkD/4KBL4yVR5w@TjegU6VMiVaOG3FNXfyLkPtHM3qOW65pV9izQkNGX4RxkTpQdlENqpKA5vNlDC4JQ3@rqkmEA6U@Hj@kXBdZGckFvewCne7pmOknyX6NoMbwHUF@Iak@xkaDGUjMfxLlEQS1dYsqVeJ1FKCcwglU@6AzWgNrsmky5Ad/EDSSBCu6CEx6EQqkVqnhdNGKcDjjkAfbGl6lpPc3bJkKYbqBSNO3w3FO2BYwSHmuoExEhmLLjR2DWW4kaHw28NsauzAyo92f7B5lb9sHqyU5aSA9tK6loD2kZLrfdApdVVW2LTV5AdqYBMxL@90o9M0ylzRrjS2VevIMZxo@9t1vd214@qRx94JgiNrfUGuoJZKS5NAWD0Ywp226vPwti2zJ6n69uiIpYySHp1YjYBB74idAVDB2IuweefQ/8ezg8kmoFOs8niJn/1PAXgKgLinAH1jp1oFCFpDsHzFJB5QonzCAmr4XoW0NObQZiwrY/RzQt/OJLAfCen7hG5bQzsvq9kd7JM/tdOu436gOedJu@rODYifeydIW8@AzFp@xdkmQmaC@zhWyF8fOZiLr6ZoLnAHr4sx4czHvPRTYXMA/WQ5QgZzpDMxTUVMAfQw7RKmPyzKuOwPIU9NKUi0pob/GAkD3eBcOO0yxgVTcIILxcwzbmjx6dE7DpaX8c8kpYnQjGIT6SweAuGPWsIgvzyBadYwAv0Q7vfSjhDZ4wi40cRB22GT7B44ZwRZL2u1KFVjnPr@viCWFwHASbnxpGzXmRzKqqpjb09cF6vab0OImDga9Kujz/Ii8Sr0J3J8TeKNK9By@yPfG35Ls2J39OEOPG1rgwnN8kh1LusiUBO7b47mzMRxpsln8GpX3IzYF1M4GC9cEF4Ap36ngmq2J5m07yqXzIGvCHDRUByxz0TCr40DkmP7Y8sfj3fcCr5EZHMBrF6ZeJwe@yqpxJyFrF4KHpX@mzMNmitdJsAncnUbAjvK3qNNt3mABSFTQ66RZxkQqq8wnkFNBuaMIZQbwiMrAuEDKilGUryiB5oZ5iXn0mLyURmGmp7AOp1EoZ/6P4KWLyQJ8h2o6E9BAp0way7z7mFPBrAECedWEnI7ngKLZQwpuLmjpPdAwKE9tudMbOxiapwBpYDscTzP/2sBVUyW2FdZUSDDM9RB0oSt7QfrD8RFV/oNr@uCeZyoGsKEYZcX0PZVHBmQ9E9x3zUqNOweLyrWD3U5UV1A7viDdrbI5zHc26p@qClus/5iRCJJ415PLah9ahE8MTBKA29H4g@ZYrk8Wk4p5tKi7DwQZemUiQLa5/Xizrkww@fdgvS6Qn5dC2GbDxF53QHzoDfcVbua/Wq9fE3nyrFSSZLZZWGrCZNW2lo6iN8YClXg5YZ7191qNCYtdwc2HH5G2jgird15Yo76@icTwBeREvrdFTLfT4EdtOFcQQNgJI39HiEVVxdi5H2rDyG09L5/SEQd12M53iYTppOt29hSGKRJrQaJC1Ovcd9ZNKmCKsrjREOBLvfzlmYICmxIHjKzWg0lcFe15tnGU/y9/sPx8eumuIXCvNj80l/TpJ5g5gkn@yPcyMYlVlM/3@l1UNfpvUUPZ5u@ZwPinXXwDp2zQElq0C8qSs2MJMjqkO9huqj22MMjt1TE9lq7HqEvcfZcafbHpq5Ea1UtOSmqWs2Nmf9ITE6bewep4nLLug2jopvs4RtkV5sd@Oea74kMJsOTps8wGhPkGx8xgLnhHyckzAfIlrTvMHfg9pG17xW@X1@b3c7N1dPkFFxnVhCa84VoK3m1zgVp97pNp@OV3Pz5TT1uf5igmBybPBUXrY13bRhkI73x0gB6rZt8/t8LvZTTVOMONmx/e750USm@iwh7HYP1KWid0w9l@8kFbg9WOEDq42SXzyfKvE8iSXLX5dYrmJkGrJ4Pijqr5LW1dc4gYzdFk6K@ZyP9LPzxJaYTHm4gDCgwJnu@YXbTuUpZiLJLSYPVYDV7N4oI/f5E3qTh6jr9ib9ESnaoPdhhEIeHI7Fle@fktrK46m1niaSZtCufq0Qvsq90lXovOg@U6UsnZK/MYacSj1dQLX1gTpQ58qng8alimsdHxl@PD1TKVGMJWFbTALx0LLoQd2KYeSTco39Nr49KmAUXYNG/lXtZq6864Mu3seR9yE4DtExG7FjDPoTlTsxfDOOHqdct@@2bLM1kUkM@VaJlP@6DjWhrtsq/R5S7bd6JgyWzR6oDcYT6l8gJTMIv08gJp@xojFhLZmbvDdzDrosqB5Qo9qVHUdD@dOETvqhET4BFwowYjNUZ4T3hyg9T4g2TFP/lpoBWdrSaE2zHsdVrF@roRk1RyyiYGNbho12kUb7ISsG72fE4BKohwNp55Ghs9829chocMbO/khv5bO6f218CT01mYlsq@m6H2JIsobIiXxi9VF25Fqo2VB1hT@GuZXH8BUSmUfxeVqHUG9plgZndvhczniaLTglevojIJbWgrFJV@2p9PqIUq@0Lge2@3gQaGjib05wIkkzEw/E62vQ1g28T8wb@bQhxzRgNOUoVkfF4YiOU6XC9yH56k54zCXubk/pqHzLw2OiY2yVwNV1fBA3ds63TxT5gpcmROPrAR5nBWg4V@rIdp9zEb4ZNaE@B72vm9mm2ngTzaFfbdSJ5Nx5nq@oe0bX7BpdtWtR4/DeHmoewJEO36zyWCEg/13FvsLlhCSPxqO5ru2nrm7q@lOoi/KQS0fTnG@p3cKtAC2I@k14R0oDAsTjqyY86LKJSNR3P9R2uuoAeibbdMy@Gqe3h0B1NPbw@3zj8@5ByGZnmmq1@FoItPwpjtbQVXajQRYubf9E9HxDUkM3FVyx@ojyDpRxn08xTTVN66t2j45iOv0@Pep9fWDTjUy88fZ822WRbVNOn8IMmsOXoXCWVTtmo9nVvpalhqo4hnaVdG04/PXRcakQxlRyjcU30Tuha0Ara5RAJij7w4/xsftQ/@eb05lb@o2BZY2@LhgmlwB4plY@ZYCOh9IXs7VzgqnLx3VW7nqiR@YtxOTug9xECjQqy3E1BVqJ/KAFaGJJmZBeNMv4gNIzVW7KjG9i7VtMl2J1ABnxNN8KB/CfZ7x4SBDuCPkGo8LwzqBjR77OuN0W6FR4m4uw2sHdW3xqydbNG5@hGZq@YojH3F7Zm4Z8bE4k@@ikSCIpJj/j6uBB65au9W1@Z/F2ei6W2dn8WajR/JGuqJ6W2ubTFOj6mmbXMy1cVw8qRLxpqXYTLd4ofblU5CLHMDsgheM6GwO7sHOLMLuAYJ5uMtnDxd/vqx0F19ntabjkTrdnOz3APL2W4CmI3w4UW3s7MB11Ls7pNQVPQflG6WjNnYlacBG61BWLsvhjohGg12xF3HQ1m5Y3u475DYezGU3PzwZOG9W9bXaPG0J8epFYZcriu8xdjeo50KyP4crctCa1TjEz/6Cg0xwymIrn3HLOX3/xmBXhZtDrD2zxmJ96Dzcr@C3HvSvyt280kILxzyB0WVfRnfnWZZ/xFPQp0ROOnQ9p2R813eywj/kUA/ULBBwq3Q8w1jr0y4eKAy3AmMOslP4T5y3RNhHnSo39GRhBzbC4ZmjO43YYx1FgHOQ@sUBc1cLNOMk9vCdefCuG@Ml8quw9KvGhSx81dRjZfA3q8MNXINSNr3ctX5l2ga7SNAZOHDcwPtZF5B7tIopsmM/5eICF3269OY24rNDpNvnixq9oYrYKI7qBrY/Grgdn/@dwmIYbtx8WsrMx3KHBptpWBrpzhDN6M/H4Kpgj2uDpbQWyY2IFK/hpltiHaCfczb5BWu1LG4PcjSIsiNuVBqhhOKaVYAQXDivRaCQS4JFwlqZjAJgLRdstcSsW38lpM6hIh2C1Njs/Z0t3w2KqKN@zMpOKEqvVOFa8aGPQ1rBPeyWPePTzJaVWXgrF46Gl0IVRZKmQB67qIKvmgisTsG2NHjy/YxIwQ@FrutHtlrjEt5rZXdrGCXp5C/T7U4PMbjhW4Bum@G68E1wX8jd/2RK7WzsqFLangb4ABMHN3WZP7Zo3z3m6IvVqv6/g7ljEAV2LzvdqxTeqDGQeDAT4plbzhp1un@TFVjmxkxxeDrmi6OWCVy6aonChu8Mrj@fGW7QsEvZiuYWCFjboGTD0ajldO8GONVrDPrDGS0bBhWCGY@H4sxVju6yl4uw7bU0gk4tumle0xwhz8jd/yTcI0gYFsXDcTZ42BvtSxH0IMu3KazbNAeTaRXKrWqYACSORoaMZoDGToewh/wgu26edi8CRcXffHiXDN@9tVI9ZfIuFcJM8bgcqae3wUvXo5bvzVK38A@sl1f/0s2TkThBO@i5eyNlSjLkgpXtkLH9wFoLHoSEmLQ0lnqC3e0MTuzdueH0AiRTOZLiBw@Ux0@yLVkN7r2mrsceN4gyQMLqpnt0NfD3atk0Mq97QBj5a22xgB4z7oQ0bGhi8Rgg1b3XlpfCA29zixw7LQoK4CVIBF9/oTfsZcDMaRlkasi@si0wWb@Iae3jjhNRx/2OvvO4u0Mr4l9ElN9XGgFaKXKcT6UyZirNUL69VyGWpLRP3IZ9/fzFMp@IXw9WtWtJ2iXpxMfwulX4PVDctiPUsiS1va3/zbilRSX35YisjJkn3oRJf9gdiYunucPdw6/ikenJ6DLVw74qfbdPqKWNZg1xEq@a7pk47vIEulqba3yB/vDcAD4fZksLW8OySSCTgX7ZNoILWUlxa4k6faJqI/ZXo8@Lbqi98FkDItLbGXI7ahd4U6xCYDamGhR/0cZ86E3HFXlviMg1lPDYgjzC4uHKOLCVSSawMxIoDsZ5IKvZwYZ9zv6dQ7KtYHifb87kgSDEvvXMvnBdxLgnufyvl7kNH@ZuXm2N5vNwE80i5AdTzdeNsV3f3To@2JqMBj9GTpG65kBX7FbhwxpbGzXXu5mLaNCYior2yLDGJIvBX0ZnRwTQN1blRoVhCODZ7PDJxKOVfCowZEyhTxtN9aiVOi3CYcoA6SAmLNbWdoq0NfVl0@2gfujteRE8IbEseajfjCUlgDtJJKwm83GIgVkEut@kdkhAX8jpk@9WfmNvisGjYR8NQiGI90FV5vY7N4N/XK7mudI0NmejO5BqLszT8dNXoQIFd2EiJ91FsiRNCWuJ5l7z84ikfkKfWpUJmA1rIJ3aMQC@tK308UkBA78NQvcg@D0za@OYKE0@/uMFBqcIPtKGqbSpYGtpQZzh4PIDbbxG@3e3jMmpnXDUj@e7nuYGBHRUA@Y6XAY3XwpOA2iTr@UEVnOSmOBPB7SrJjmyLPdCelmCza80mOzNWQht1HB0kJZZGFBzPdqItj6yq26CTtKD75ichkXKSoOXnfA163GBSEHgy4amMMSYFENYuz@6Rh670pgnd6iceeYngCLPtwxlaW4zHgXIdzXDPIiqiOZzshEXmWANctFEJzURxs1AkV7zr9HQf4JzTQi7U5I//9M/4CSEXDrh/LtzD1Dq8/aF4a4P7n7ghsgxv/8x7S8PbH/G375NYZbPHIojkxSjpwbX6wJcvpJkyoUxwD2Sisni1jTX9bveQ2WSzx7rsKUNfNaGEQZ7TDKCX1gOmuKY6RnCewrgKx3jC5@@ARYCvgD9QvUGNhtJTrVoYN8cXk0nMOBoWErTAWx1ygz3tlf88wDNiQAlL5rK5FTkJmYxfuwhpw2oHVxRzhJFIEWRi4Frrlz81mrhzhEl2U9HVcq7EeSO5pHyfkT55GV0C2AAfKJwziIObTbwYEFYR0cJLSlSOYFTsyEJyCGVay@SsBtpgmBwAEkFvw92XB@qmKUgFfGyoQ4c0ppE7AGrgWWBoaFT5SUEuojgg4rjxJJPp5jheI4ybLHwNNOGvBukMwY4RrCjNY9bz79mFc2HUxIk2DBjvl3NY1wD3P55zzA3nLNzCO3u@Snj6dBQsDXtxbJi4lnwbcsvC6WQ6k5RzER@HSgIV5Beb@hdACY0bhEVT1S7Nvl3d2Np9dXB4PHNOCEGGpsFCLFRZi17EE7HzmucIefmeJOr6dvL4zfq2S0p/rsbLLRBivOZiOpvzUpvO6QOpn/HF2bNpU8BMQnLqqYhpgjO@TUuSZrGPQ5M@wA2@NnQm1XDk7v68tla5MIIzyX@Zd3ZSMLGMzAWuC5tOTgpNZxOzuOsuOT/BMxnthLsZKS2NTwbztlDx97H3wyd9eCc8jo/7cBe3B2i77HhLbeKBZe9Q9kSSJ0VnXfCMufkFWeNmVcasjhNsBmaWzPhzw0RZZg@jFPvBPCIdcBuSe5SgzSFtEs7cykRn7ng08@BOXIzY9McHcIiTJ7qQO11rBG7EJml3N523QTph93XNCUcChoCY3lc3C2k/eo6FB6aUz4fM2yBmo844TJDBNUzHRN3UAvwYEOae1hGlAz8OB0C3Q7PPxla0TdV1HYFOxTYHkEQTB2SvBj2Aa9PjSMXeQgUtKw6RgZ4hNyvneMSFoESi18qGh5FEVx22tA70OOFIDETTd7I8PipEwbMuQK9qzCsBmqX6XQXKgFWTWcOTNoaRtQK9jgvIzbLsZr63UQsAMozaiBS55SJ0arinOmHFF1ko5lGmEYmFEoyPpMSBTTTtT4aoBNvo4iJJMn202xqpbP4N@Lwzb2tWL4Glgm6Gs9BLXCLt55pvOrXFRxnlXEloRksdhnGDfLGGdAL/0M3ZdSgizbA4HR0jDgppTZ8h48pCxRFCaXz@ypS8KxQ8OTcpGgoF3GSPWw1hUAIpHjvWHjhBRQi3e0qfhQd0CI/NEoxewxdhI2Y7VoTFK9hd3zCDRaNk04AHBcCYBUHb5NLotIMwnlkXTpahktDXNlr4uNX67FxOJGrgpkQibAntmRugTaElMBKAMSpEKRJa0C/gr4g54ieMJsRJo0uUbIDOwQCoucEkp9C2DvIFaEGlZpVnvvMDxgKGU7VQKIramJT2BQZ8sTZHIALaOVLcHSMAfcXWMKAaymiA2rDUlgby8sVr1TBUIBDwTA8PVFUGwGRWJOae9Rsbn8VHKQR5FnfEXjPI6OQZfVuhO90EdW0pWSLTWOke1JpPF6jXtIVmM0r@t8lEsnQXXtLLoyTompFKeKlblqOZ5Wh0yVgOLxmobT17hha1@yVQ5uoJGKAOASi@pEdKwM@g/JWXjNKSshZeapXTyxQDXmGIfAcRfrCTibsl5T659AyUpRj4WFzohJdsOj4nlUjI95A/bCFLyRjwzB2eA0Mn@GLyS1o0inlILNUxAz8kL46j1G1eHCfJeFcSY4Fkpyea25Qq5tXEzMnDnIDCu@h1WFnssMS6wboLPD6hLzMv7AH1jyf8GldXM1oUotr@wZc0GfJ0wSLkNMpcIWTC/PwiIOAwDETE15gSiYAw@fWvg3KOMel5LhM2o8@zqVI0lJVhmA7j6@AL0MOTy5Il3V1sxq@Z2k7nPsfPlXbic@3w6vDwfeQizAosFNw4kOQV6Xs8ZPlp1ypLP3Cxn34Fg8vJQDC5LD9bTSY/ffoEIw64ziuJCogPfkXO46HaeXiVscrq6nIsl1@OvQjVfdmKhNPpyDHTtCS70Pp2qwU/s0vHbYeD/Hr@nNKC4T/8M@4n0hcO9wVBhG/wG@GulWyQXawqynJ0Jf3CKCXSqfTf/LvF@9jdYX3tb36vl1QX8XGAj5/fv0H3sZz9bnHxu/X1lZUYEJK7Dz8efqhWqyubsezhefb5Sjy1uPYf/4/FxXR6LZ1crNm2XAudX72X0qkVKfE3fxE6PHxbt20gRAGvDJPBifc8/GSWzbIrdgvXVZvhP7lvWz63gu5G@xbPLILxSpmETSiUzYSOvw/Nr7ZFJleer/7nPz74HHSClXTyzIKnE/wczOWD3AkOeMu4b9fBSnANwXL3wVGyXC6Dc/U//68Qv/IK8GDIaA1ulayLKzcKVuJlivIlWMmBQ06nId3/62c/CwQrw@BtUJbl4Ij@6uiGK/9MfsbQkZRW85JpvsADwfEa@q5xKZKynL5w69NX3Vi1nncXcEO9MtPn59W7x1VMcAM5ngpXgdsWXn/7v//tn/7tH9Pfn9LvP@A507nFF582GVOhB8arWHwxUw97U@9HiThcCa91BPE1LkoWzJdjdZ4rj4WDPscUHbw7EyTx3r8RLhB0D0tFOVSbqIyLoJxfOXgxfPLFxpl2aRsck9RLnE37uZXhvTBXFrBvgQsEfyiXjxz8e9PAv0Mb/9jwp1zIDs/hWoQ/@ofLe8X7IvkIbwKZvRZ/A@kbCJ4Hz2u1HQP/Pnfpz8K/xmf827vFv88O/p008e/oM/6d3OIfmylNILi2thaMRo9AZRRM@5TrFH6JRF28ecwbDAR/qxdbOcgdvAhAm6hF4/f354nvh9FSSfyDMlXy3vDiLshW7T4eX/u@Eo2eU/bOKyKfa/FaBfLKs0y379cAcXTtfG0tUa9UKvHa95XztclIIt6LF1FsqC8gYqV2fh4I3mFdlPG2jLemjfe0JCXpFcU69NMFcDFy0kN4MPpQAr4Hgp/WPoWjz6PPU3rqOiVfyVdvzIPx/8HBEAK0YerStFLdVFdugaRkKfU0NUqNhqmeeSC3wKnCX6oHTi3VHqY6KSNlyPJoOIHq4f/egem8OTABmwkxnWHKQcSpNjw7BwdvAF8b0r6EPy2VSg0hk8PUNfyndJTbdAYbPb@vRy4C50z6pIJWkJBDiVQokQuFtFo21/8sxUL1i/NQrRRM2hcXSa4vsfRKic7eu7@v17f2N@v1JHLQ2lL0RTT@Aq5yJbomHs@DldLzi2Ica45zXqIeTK49v6hk4ujORaF60uC3lox@4zVGCc/K4kUAhoBnZ/g7u7m@4S5ykOvi7MwLxVsSvchFXnABaHJu/AkHA93zd/TfOvgv6//NKQuf1yKMhe/u18J0RfAvErm7v7sX90okHBYv4TX4Qw94xyh39xV0EtAduM7DkVrk/p77wT0cWeMIK5jGWoUijwGhqQZ5qhehEmMwVgqLabaLi2EqFSk1wMczuCtfaMYmUqK1LEsNnGWD8YG8HCGQ7EqptCLcq/lSKS/cci5XKi17UCl4EU4AUm2lWUJGLwX7EcwDZ/9wCs0sdMBpKNxS23jS/fN@H8Z6ciH15YvnVa@3NKteR//Mly8X0JJCuJSlXMiCTyr/5Qs0v1AExoH7pphELcCoTk6mx@i7iq04jhWGkX7sIoTLzeyLUATD06kUAmN8ll1by61UKrkVcOfykUhJWuLrYMKdaEGO3C8lJV4MGKGFgiJIzq9GyPc@hOEsuMaeV4DDbbzY3X2QqM1WspFwY6RGPA@5UOA@bCUXzkcL4q@8GGFrycoyE3/n55noyvLq8otabdxzoZgo3Sll@b58pxTRbHBfaorjRXF1p/LsWaYAdMmnSheBen2zelKt43cacEoapC9DTxI4AZxu7Fuhc7LxZAu1cyxJ7SIUKpZe8IrNZ1kwVBJw8RCILpYvUIGDMJDU2rise0hY@a8oL6czi8ns8LvcVgoU7y/LeJ2fn@fT@egyiLblQqFWq5Hvl0WKc94btmt0zFQ5fi7nsrU4qi6Xw/ZysM/k1UxwOdCnxUWrKdbC@VkLbWaL4An1yho4lW6ruu6e6HpjWnrrRmupgP1wr7qxdRJLrwHK9HZ1I5Y@Pl0PyviaHb9TcAbfj7aqmwenEOFwb6t6vPVy993W6SH429A/ArHg6h0q6kCtqzeDwQ2@11W6NjRbubxU@v16H65h@8df/sGPv/zvfvzzP/rxz//gxz//01/94k//AH5/Cb8/4s8/@reFLN5/9Yt/9j//@K//HDz/A/z@Pfz@3a9@8S9@xn/0/tfw@z99fn8tfj44/gNSArY//NUv/vgvfvWLf/Iv4fevxO9fTv9@/JP/jf//R/GHzj//8U/@Gm/i5Q/@6Mff/@Mff//3fvz9n//4@/8QkP/9X/0S///4r/7@3/8S//@Xf/P3f/U//P0f/k/k@DPu@L//1b/l97/7vT/4u9//53/3e7944P4Hj95/8QT/X/wOfJ6ez6fgeUq5vtXnFz8pP78JNcapEIP96T/@8V/8I@DcP@Fv/z28wb8X9HPvxQuJ0qAuHh17/pyxL0nQm1IvvniggPJ/RF/wZl8msZFvyvX91S/@@V@g9wTsP/JjSMmzsEsI7KX2c4D9117G/LA///GXP/vxL/7hj7/8sx9/@Yco0OIrhVg1Fpe/YhcCwOwT4BAw9xQ4AJTXcIp8kS0G0uBYXEM7RkCOfvoEJF0EF@jfy4FsBt5wHDN91WoVvC7Ok5WL5EWFXzV4TyQr6JNIXiQxPJFEjV6uEDLIVTQAKcN4aJkbIqJof4DfMLBSgDc0TUShC4ryoCgErUdZuVyOBoZlCCNQeMU4Q1bJ46ALxxxlwIuReJxYPQ9aLRuuExaIWY4esfpyecgjRtGjQhgYZgi9jiQ5LUXz5U1IsDzcZIgLkUcDn@D5qVzJl4cVRPcDZQFwRNchSYAqY@6GlR/gvUw4AT4w3PwBspIvR6OVPPiUqaiUWqxOacpZKhyVPcqo3OgPA2B4PH/B2HeSnJf42A/qgglovEfH0M/JBPIcwi@iy6I49O866beM8aGih0Qf7sfDn6M3xRcAgDcex/VY8IvHMTcvIHjIUUUpWXhEOQagXFSYkDwP6qajgSjVb5ReIH3Iw9OutYrvBdFhcZaWlsC1VpEy0gEMJZh1VbQdxcLpClKSikzKFST0xuUt6tIhDTaWN5fhLsP/1iItUeXkWA4shVAXCDE3jXg0Y66YQcq9WzQqyzLlPEpwgeDYnyu4NOcEmukKiwTCdMZ5hMaqar8Pzzd2Z90cghIak6SYnONW5YgYyn4wi8XyD/LKagCe9D7A49XFQd9QDfjJrQS2MiRo5S5OLQ6doK/kApWKmDdjcqByvHUCEU4OmJxOJRhorncrq@mV7Eo2ncnlsqtpeSVXWMll8xkQcblUNp2WCysrhXxh9Z6y9AJERay43MiuVf7BzPXf/IN513xfvAKV92yYYPH7QGUYjyfTlOOynF0tjcqQD/IKVEgT4zr66C6OyyUDF7Q86w5XAkG2AndxZNMFuFhgIcAWwAsuQIszBkxMY@8elMR8Hn64gs/pSXIWGCESuABG4NgC/ekrgBX3DKTNM5k7s7mxM4XOE9w4tQ9pQDUYbA/XTjomOzH5Gr11tRlYE1t@KoEATYCcA1FrATwZ/rwWWEt6ofMxbXT599w2LBN03J8Os64YVzxoU8NzGpuOF7Sj4GlMdk9zug9AnPZ7uEVItX5nGLZ6DcggGjo5wDrcLN005wGsstPDB0r5xtuIiTOJtBMTwI92X@6c@J4nW9WNnUCOrR/sb049sgIoy/a2tk@811Ue6kbNeig@bO3tTb@KB45TFll2NRYD@Qg3fMboomdi6XsXRE483POmYvVj/i0D04bGKgNP19V0li0VZBgarqYKmUK2sNq0yuvRo/ogLz1flDIwFm0qrJNdTQHrnxqDYTudB/lToo0lZbkUTBVzqf1BL/AGl5MVZL4tQrMDOzCw6eFZ73gsgBOw1BYMcm4M2vHRwC82DfrsQU94oBc6La3ThQRvTBcg0FAUBr9vvSC@6r@cxz0cngb5zYToc8BxAk1rs1QgQUawdCGfzRcy6XwsX8ivZGH8l43J6Zi8ml8tpGJySs7LuXy2IMfyK4XMCohGCAXqB4IgQrR2MgmSX5YkegKt8TzWNTzY1kx0K4EgtyFAd4ufIgwqnscgz6RM/iIF8aQALpVlWnlRwo99pvBTmoBQYU0W3N7eSG1vS9I6vqCpbyMlSS18yeZTqdV1SVIpZAOkd1qSTB4HggDM4S@p1PqGJA04AtxBKkldfNnKoZ4qSRq@bFS3tzGdS3xJY3wAu@Ih/EV3X1YBzMCXTIYUXUn67KEDuCpPaIVyuoUvmCaGbPOQDQiTpJduflIpwHDE4TiGHbes1aok7fKXahVDXlHBszyrr/GlSpckWfACPChJHXB0LBiRS1IDnMiJktQEV3OkgF8PXLjZ0HAUSRpxAiGJJGlI0ErzSgKdSvhjMjs7O0rXaakdfo0s/mxC1iBEGw62thsvXzY6nYY1qm69PMKQV692lMvRwGp0GiJaow6XCXEg5Ko3mr4gj7v1uqLPDXkNIcZUSH1UVzFvdeUz5ElcHUykV38FIa8gZN4ECscGVw9AG3it9@C5rjQoxL0ohJ7DRkMqIY86o76KphZsMrTkqOT36SlNyyyhC5RwthgKh2Kjc7kWuy1RCOsxFo7cpUr3CNIO03c8UEKCxnM3Oh@WUzVQveUSWoHCi73nklzISsVF5Xl4iO6cVATle0WKFPEbKGY7xEJx@TnIvdyqVFyGp/RcyoBzGE6FUozBLXK@WnsurSIS6fnzuAR5gVcAUSCitFpAhIVVUARK90APB2RtY@Co9Xo4fKMqV5EILxP/bhI7OzuL3PFlVhqV0Sm1w8PYsMxzw7RI6RYyP42ppUJ3N2g6psXxdYACt89TRSokJJ@XIHWWTEbWUCChCIHnJzJjJ1gxzr8YIudzkQQuyq6b7Tqd3c8@CVs386zegTPcPUE7J91lNqT@2sXACSqK9MlBhtuyG/iVHtrzCyMQfj4EfVNHBbWxEAhUhOZ0og6dxI6KS16a8fjZ5LW2FlwDSNw9jF0LdClsnd1QOriDwV3EXS@vA9JUycCTDFR8XRoGh4FKS3EUGEGt3w2KRYC9L3XK5xj5C97W4tJZ5UyqMX@qa2vnX2qgMAKN2@yWOeXbqFMaBZUyyPAGKLUrpSG8yKsrJX@mwpESBZazqehqflns0cBPNN@EHXPLgGynikXcUIslUGLko0TKFSUSKYUXI2Vb/cxV0S86Gh8X6@UUV0qX7EHvPLWYk2N38Xr8XldsZ0leTRfPB0vncbm2uJj60lmTPlakGpYD1VX485tHoWspgZ9b57wzGncnY79@CbQFXQWVSS6kSwIk0BeMF5ZYGL/hxJf8hEOh1XQoFAmVAGoRvIl/I3fEbiFoBKFnwPrQnQHvF9IQbqnOALQoaJQzOeC6d04OBO8DLc3us5VCIHgXuL@7X6u4SsprNhop0bj7@oyxThRGYUmazsGJoEVyxROVF6xarnaOqiUBWt2gsVIywC74RrJ4cvFbJ42ia5Xv@fMCpwohmQAnDs2oJteiFbItBCRJCkquxT@cz8IAC80YPwTp3ES2cdceGHSWQvENkkspcr3rvBb5YV/T7/KZeIX0d@Cm@/tgdC2J05CJSpKI1TygWfpA0DCFE@2/DjQeaN/ZrISjOZX1jwvfr36f//7N6cHpwTZ7kSrmi3lOiQs@wIrJITkElH0BioV2tBUI9r@YWfkH41UpWOyHMiuhzIR6eFEW26jDyAfhc5wigV/tHMZptQi4ymX5ubxa1GwxgxEu2oO@akWey7l0MZ2SI0G7gns806tBIBK65NxqsBbkSFdWI@Am43taDlaSwltexXhx/gYsnA3awBT5N5@@wMhbfHVWS5MrmRQ5Xbpfu4f/yv05DE7vaYx6T/94S8LtngPQP0ZwX@gxvibgxjDj8NoP8TX@v0a3jQOeaSkHtRD8BI3atr@vf18PBoKFUCWaDOEX1Pk1FKM@1A2XDfpT7WX8@37ssWzb9rL3Bq/LUGaWrcgMtMlk8iLyNg16ZKGQy@eCgV/PXsllGKUuL1RZiJ9LxKU0nkrobSIKTXwHCg0LywvxzeODjdcwfgcxrRr4HU@2cbCfwCD81OR4F1hTVxVLH4lvTY4QCqX7ycYhfo3@dPOQ4pzR/j/yJfuBSGVpt1UUH2SJXTM5kcFJqWwytZKUs0zOF1OrxXSOKSCHbNzvL1xLGJVRsTbM/ohr/@GNCEVeqCIMhu1pMB6z1SJ7ebhHMegogOWFza03B@xgf@9DwvXl/ic7u8fs@GD75Kx6tAXleLN1zKTqMds9ltjZ7snOwekJq@5/YBB8VN0/2d06RgTJAMow1EY4wTxVnK3ZIzuJqopN@viEt202r1Rn0l@x@koSj9mc9DbwKxwqHlU/6T8wYFDb8qv6x9UF3u8zRK@0WlYANx5qTbaAev7Csmrh6lypm7JXWXbw/jZlZRdZc2U/tMqaqX0js7bK9JT4Y/pKL3PEFhcXLwzJ6wD8xfBGGn4vXLIOfuM87X7cWgjnVtgyjC/SK5FxyP7B4ULKfVs4OzpZkL2wo82FtPeyu72Q8V624G3Fe9s@21zIem/r1dcLuXG0/Y2FVe9tc2tjIe@9AZMuFMY49zcX5FTAJda1qbUW6Etj4e3dvS22DECR0kQoWnXQMeUNhAgPDJufAkFDq@Xlm64ZI0W1MZqCbqlfg3bBJ6AWUI05R7rWYmzZ7MOtp/YAGKIFPM1RsTrNmMCKR9JAtxK4CyxggRawQAC/gPuPEY4tllk6wiB4oc3nx8P8iLIYk05t2mX4nc3WUAesADPE6Iwb2m0KMVTxycHAwr1AGW6T5atNS2gJFNRxJllSJIJb1PZP9/Z4YtAxWKYVlgiS0Ys0B6fZB2xQRLhj0cGXVw6vFqoLpNWC0Crws4iB@4naDEzXJpICyrmw0AQEk9S9VvQYQ8UqhvOuiBdf@NJ3AIZgcKfAxffmhcNNLGtHdZqUoQgSc@tgm5cQZ27LbLKWIwwTJUpRMF9U/@ULc98unMlXa/LVCHHcAjnPFsfHc1pG2Aj6LbibIgmCNoBTzAXkmGgUYkNxKMxXrgUgOvz4fnE3lxVIKBViz55RPtbgrRCiJDBelFJkcQRBBIJgRD5E5mVtkbIbWUgu48IK/k1xJCL2I/zUy8bIO@sCJOt0Rqdq1WuFXnUuGDDyKU0JZBHUbmFdgzuTrsM7ikfg5BhrQDOJMTdQzmEgDkViTI2xNnhPydS6ZgDnqtZYJrqsAI2Ran9/k9cQP9iF/LkHlRjkXpEqDITFM2y@xOgLCw0Lxn8lFwrkIUEB3yLThJEQHO7xeEebFG2ZtxdkS4z9lJi720WXj3hsYAfBaURW3IvPeUUUlzwrY6AZ/AIZtt8yoOcsyZFFowLC4zIBtjUJF49zuHuXL79SiK3pUix@cylQLD9Yiq0nFuM3KwV0a2MWgVKAiA8D3ihA022yNtPzUEBfSCioND8NBXSgY16CNj6B4Anxocsdx49/e3zopIvTTRnaLdQglwo8yuRrc/K1NfmKzRd8FAZjgvQK@8Ia6JJz4MI92SwPjhaXlZMR25OvZKkoM9WN0/YkME8BeA5FJQdDBpwVxihBEjae0K/08DsxZVbdru/ub51MhiK@hF0XGe/i99gpjcgkmMgQhtthfIl4OQq3kQhc3wwf8jRiRM/68cnRVvVNDPIXYWvjFjCtA8BNtISJEty7KYCvoTahP27FWPi4ypYj7BnmLMaEsQBfnpyEbtoqoHowxdagn6akUhzEe59sSUFskYE5SUlhFo6wLxcX0KWmVpnc63/J9DLGaqbFRplVVHY5Hk8HEVLeFTD7vGlyZQMhW/w4tuLcxC5TKbZiZZijdkHjHqasWfxUrnvs26hbdHeO9k0alNklhht1UbaIczagX5xUbR7XIqlvRD5AX2zG4IfdORnDoqSfI3tSqKtg8by01G/Ny9c02sm8xHle1ijR2Tz8WlgEYbgUmNodTMeVmH2nr@AGWhF40EdjyiF6WYEAN7L4Tq0Km/htDidSpNNGUKbU63gOY70etlW9jd8FH1hN6PJRXbYFGF4YmuCB1JDQMRkoyIP602RAS8MNr3hcJvQ6Uwjp8@RlOiMvTCkGAl7ObEftU6582UA7GX7F1p8gDLAn3qFacSOaL8eRotCKtxVsDy6y84mDhjiOgd2NzfEG8Tzr67HpnDCPbeaE4Xly86K4G6TnhF0OevNyAILhgRCxxXFOiGEezIvAz@kZB9TOfQQ89xO4VgtH5lc9tKvJGvcdtET0P7EGqjg1aPfAx4KgXAoO9NV1cFMFpm1qeOL5NCJvkzXEDA8jvv3eHltFxpyk2E1Nm0bvYhKIaMMiHerNhsVmF7B@J6fzkZgPoQ8jHgTYU/SHcDIfUsjhHCRBdky875o/bQ81suA03nH8BB5XYLRgeDeOYPYfgcfQMSxWvgu8gCdNeSEeM89pcmN0xVnGIX@0u2P1yxNncj0E7RZCjvgJ@psmH//W5OO@9LFN/qSky@x8Mh@1qO@9CB7jMroN/Ccl5OZ6MrXIN5XYzzWqevUA@@LZKb5k@JkJk8l6aIQE8njKLQqhR48nCgnE5Uf0DfKFqk/s6J4Xe9z/LJdZXPbicIk3bg1kV/dlPoCnPdTreExqvU7n49XraFmq1yWeAnW82OH5O13R2HhYArTUukmhYSmuSDEpHq8eb@zuxjVDivFDpMuS7ZiWWsdjrqQYTlqWJRJYdYTpqnq/LInFZIrNKLb0cBpVXxpQwK8nQkA8lV2DEhmff/r15Jr@IplPKJI5ldj4TMYnpHZEqeH288dSsvjhZm5CG3T@Fh5oZqkaChp@PLb4BDQeVDFxPgKa9EUWeLo2WfpsPJWCZ4kedfQTdY3HO9CHtsuMrH2Se16LNHO8imjtaOpBBGNO5dwnHdJHdBid3dVShZ5F5qGEND63UWQsIUrq43dXQePHXYw7tMkzXER@Y65t0kYz5lRWx4LF7GPhzyU84gUq4NDsw9075gXc3kEv4MajXtDLFXXgxnNeMEZbOMSRL@CiQ1/gCewtjc@Y7ClDrTdAw43/IAGhyY2zhV0@loR6fQqclH6cogiR0PGw3rDAG4lKRQmKbtMBM9OHzCD8vHNmIrXArJClU5Exmz7VYR7SuSfXRGK/hUryKWIomm2RG4gbk5jElRCKKxdrMPj08Y4rYlB9nvIzudUTEUFJYl78cX/lO6emPDG8QIrA4IFnZhyBW5n8H6sj5T5S9FSQcY35objiNiffuBb0wYz7MbiKWiTwyEjq/zfjJH@V/Bc6VPr/flA0M/T5HQ9lHhnCfPNo5bc4LPivCv1/Veh/gkL/W9PmH1DJp1HOtvgpdf2ravi3q18k80bQbVidazS9pX@KHvZbUgRWv0kPcHN9Lj@mC3y9f3bRpP3d@k/spQO/Tp60cmfbZrVaPenJ1tHLaqfarR7hkUDrqb3o2eXK@ubN@sv1VnVzs/Oqs7Gvvs1XV/b6r9/nP7xs335WQXvfOXj18VbvN7uB90f9mzP18Caj5u3qYPB5d2fk7Kyf9jaOsx9Wb1Jbera9rn7e1O3NNyfvX5@8zB5Hbz6/Onx120v17MN2Sin0Mjtvcu82RmdGIHutnba297SD3nFr6zTd29vUPmxHN1J7x4W3cmpv6@ZjZuMmmk0ld/uvD14enV42tj7qR7t7H1obn00l9/nqpr@bbBXaG5dH7wIHmbfyzueDg85WuvByJ3mz2e63Uukd3cpevj86XD/9sNN9rWz1trOnhfeXo8Nc9@3ba2c/2lk5yw3e2CtRo/r2bfq18fL6euso0FDMEyujnplv5f7NzaFZ6K2qr/d3Or23lmwkD7Lvose9k5vNrXX98@owc/rh7O3NyvGHwZu3rz4epLTj48aWkus3Wunjy5OVQLOX2Y1en26d5pWXrbO3vevdneyHzeSbrrpfbR3qVy87Ox/N48O93WrGHhjy3sa1/uFl9/LN1ebGrm4eXulGdSWZ1U9aHw4OAqevtMamuvPeflW97H5IZtevVj5EW/2XJ5e33atX68enB/n08HCUMjfso8ZOe7h5lEvnk03989Ft23wjn76N5q4vX6W1D9VbJ5C5HWULe/oHtWe8ijY7H4ef9WT0VJY3Pu7efvhwvHNtNarG6ed320eX1puWcWAfpI5evX7T0K/yzmX/o3F8LDdTL9WrN9GUEhie7thQR@qJkl096e297Q83zc9Hux/t3G30@uwqo25eHb2rfj5KNW6M/nvD2tN6G6nWgVJ9Zzpbg@HLZuH69GpH3/t8YH8IvNmSs9lts22vt9@tFN4nX0bbVy/fr8vHw9S@cdReyVn7796eadpW9/3p7VEzu/2un@85Ruft7WlvK7q1N@zeqvlUQz/@cGUETrPHR4fpG@O11nO2d47e5JyD1N67w9bOSK6@VeUbY3VjlN0cWrnM2eZ768PVjtFPftA@Dw5T6nW09aHvrLzVGu3mO63Zex04ftU93T98d7ObzVkve4a2fphP7e/tbOx3WiuvR7tvBlt7jcvWy9336vv@Se4qvbV@ltt8f5xxTq5eO4XmdS9zmI@e6D2ncxoNvBp0B6uHZ9bnd8OPK9VeQ80c6R/M0arc23jVTw/fVbcObjtXh31zX95Oj5Kne@aVnro9ubndsXPVUTQ/PHV6pnMiD7Py20Dm5rbvvOq/ent8sP7q4OMrZUXTzpTL43etVOY0n9S6VmY3l3spb223e597BVW@3XyTUTK9btTeu0q2Nlqn786u9Mve695lM5Av2M313Y8DxdxqpOXUh/X2VlbdW987kdXTzuvjlc391OH71uHp5@FJa@P94PTdgZbaunxV2OusvD96V3i9@vHEPlHOzPevrf3AMJ8xbTlXyN5kjgv5g651nDm7LDgfX1/m1vWzhvxqN91TtzXrfX6Uv@rfdm86N8dqqtF5uflZOWpvgSQ9PUwp2cHV/vA4kHl30rte7a9HP1w1X783ZD1/pq0mTz5fFq663dc3m82Vs@rtZyX78lItHG8nG/p29mX0aOPt4WVn8@w2v9JKre@9U94Pt7rOh8DbHW3zsnB2dTAcyW@3j0e9asrQs9fHZ9nrE3P9@GznON9907DajZ3LLsiG3uj08mZwvaOudoc3@dfdy3dKau99fsOwVw5TgVfqbq91dPL6fTXaTqsF5/rgw37/LH82zL7Jm2cF8yCvva62Xw7fHrS3Uqt97exkeLrVTa5vaL08yJRD/dTaOHi78/HsVT8VSBu59dsNM7v6OXo9/JA7Sx5G9wYfmifp3pll7bzXrO3314fvXx9Xd6O7jdHLwyvl4MNW9nh/Y8N@Fd3WcupoJ3NjVzcyetsM2L314f7Q6hcyH6/2OtATmK1C6@VJ5sywq9X2zW7@eKtafWk3dl8pw@HL9ir0EXhtnb0zy4Ff8@PeAvykN/5Q@NkSgZ7daZhDkJd8b1qANhsFaLNRgG8voiXSfPnxr5PLgRP/Onz61Co38AwaoKyxlonKQ4Ltemey4icZYqxnQnQNXU2zT09EK7YTtHDAp8Od7FW4@40@FKcO@7qp4ddu8OR9HJNaKt9iB@pLInBgsN4Ix5uO2uO7AzT8YI04QpUO6@ffBaIjHAMLzSZzP6eXoANCvY/rfQIFom904nQibIfF4822rnRscOgtcn0KHHsnlmMKuqag8QOTkPfqipzKiqWpqK5S5k7wOzv7L5lu8k8BuCMOBZSJEZ2rgUYqOltDxU9u2dq1qo/o2w5qKxHgKz6ftArS74druyf96BjLqbWhoG6o1tQC0D6P6M60Jpdf4LEnL5aTYooVlaG6YjU0Bz/oWufbDeo8RXfNW39y7SFtSxUTtFwxQs2GDoCNiV01Q3ybioUUozXmuKXAEcmjaogqqrvacHm5Tyhp3RXjLz7My/2HcWu9zm8L9QTulqZO4DWBVgOgFU1Iz8zZf2fTIkcPqBTgk/Vb73dP6uIDIHyJ4cRenQdWXPqoXHLf@iVeAl/@Rc5nl2XiCgPIPpod@fnJUNRrk/OyROsecXkk1DaOsMerLemD5Zh1xNan1SjnKzW@gjBFS/dcgntxnnFOeObL1bMxQRfEggqPB54Yjy/Q5CCz5UXEbUtVCYBWc7pbQ6YW@/2Wee@BmmnoinGFrhJfKgvjBavpqyz6tIGvHGjK8soi1k/SGAHLDVG9ZbDjjEqWVy0EIBbEutV8amBzpvX2GIfXsJc02scwDW/UpetmMzwOXnaX3PCyRdyUOPxUUgdoSWzjylrTGvGE0DwTLpUABNfpkExQDXe1qq/U5TE1EB0t6vHlAvi25HrhHnh1nM8Yezy3PKlFYgdaATQ/q3wxEEKde9mq8aQeloVA74i/MBNRx8RxlxCBM7nMHLMPRGgLjoNujHiEr06doQpf6eVxEeN0Ok/V4J89978U@cJdbFAqmj1RhESwGeMIfSpzXqYRtOI1HUxqzHpUUbiCG6tQI15kGozw0Z9p0ehEPfmQn2tIN5lFidrhOaEghrwSCdIL2hMMrYmD2uBLcVmbr@DitA5MkWgNEvryxWsw8Opx46G7fRBYwvt8NDI450zelgVBS@672wg9N4WMieJJ1fvZtfS0MRIG4OZNXxuqehgEZh0/bNJn4CWWLPX73EEQ3vIl8MbKprwLebW4GIZY5wSXzNfYMxaW19bCq/EweX2Xj0S8xiiip33RfZFBSFcqLJxeDmfcyCsYGVBmJhGszEeQ5ghWlsOyiyAtEMhZwMBVDELyHctzrp1EnPch9vDWJmHw8yhzUl9OR@Xa2loe13j6PKcip@dnfTkTTUNkjnohOhnC0fIAn39tskSAPJP29SM@FCvRDKDgSUcnA8apTgV4ifrTXKnN7Zx@a8qLu0/D7XwoOn6lUbXO81he5FS@KL3PwN13LOGJX8rq0/eyxn6cpZeRzUFHoCYJqXVV3DQV499LE50W0K801Sv6NkcQBIoBIoKLR4uxy8f6usa3d3YI3CYDHy9zjMkxlodhCEgUkBh5iAwihGigderNXt@Dg644H@ErvnkHRons44wz7h@AekK1302JxBgnH85wAz7xvSrqQzh9wxChvre7jo93W0e4YnZ3/yVU4QKWI8bGd7eYixyjV8QNxeDf0NAcDbIAso0PaERZeVVNpo@ebvoCm4tcwE9j5xGpdAjBeGShHRJfaE5dMwU2TkqXj1SH6EifdPIA8pESjDPYjcoUHckx4p@izfMvP9GmN4pNpAKHF1FkECmENDs5qu4fbx8cvSHKHdare4c7VcQMA8ymYrUYfZsEG4hhqDrvVD16BrD7BQnNy6Q03A9p8G82Iyz/yB0nHgDWKaROvtM5wvJypp@B597zIpBE8aBBqai31P4c3Lh21QMThbHnIOS1yHMtukKRp3k9IXV4sz2hK0crKOmIlqZqGyEHGJu@1aIYXJ4kXXzrMMqkD91Ry0U9qkP8YvEve2XS9Llf5CN70MfZYbUl@cmvNJuqTfv1x9QHlKrepkSEZPERCnzml34sP/jeFK/vFTjoa4fU6aY8vXes5k4qi6A9ctr9JB3XpyBxLK6OdOeqlaQWiZT514cnVEdtUmV8KDGe2iVP7RJS4wKXXU4rZFrt/HJCEZtHHs0lzyXXjV3NjKsn3lJyqrk2NHq7i6fkkC2ESx2qMKwmOiHCHE3IumdulT1zW/G4Jc5X7h5XygRhJzUy0eGM@08xYG61gGzhGdsG7Vyh0dfAwvrnL4Z6gy/UU/KNTu4Qg@CJU@qgTrtwrvjEPVQPcgZiAmlIu2XORXI16lQ8fGGBkMXd/ER8ugbtwhRWAc0AaTHenCbKSqqkaYuBos8Txaroha2W28gJctyZWa3pDV0IhL58w@F4VwLfxscTyqOTvpRYJtTIIWOdlQK4rhqPQ4QIt2uQTgPiFstA2dOc@cXIzxZDFM7VyTS@AwZFnXDLXBQg6BcY94Cvm3hpbrl95XA3w2HkiK9gqZLYQeHu6D09ZBk5k/Ft/z0422e53Hh3MB63xVbSqfGWYzx4i@UKgZ9kJxvbEzg/YsMRFYpshTyDQ3fQBVVdh0bMHy0Nu37MGx8WD/ljVPKUK3F4iC3EsegabNbDb7A3VPzWOM7XOkweyonAAgjFE99X7N3OGwA7A8VSDEfleyxRkIuZXUyQIqIOq1o2/8I9feMdJD5@ghy6BUvlBmDwaZlNWiSJOCge1PSgR6uRYqgwXKsWHgOgOWKj/wLJHMEOXDRUOBO4nq5wqLi8wUkoRAK1aDSycDJSt4zU46YX4UqTunKyl6JcnuzJ1KW534PFDBB5BasQjbk7sCAIPNPN0Hh8WXwUy22SHvBY9M8zDc52Mnxw6o7DBRrex8yO/LXaHGMMcVfT3wcNxSImQkVlqkXcPXAkAdwtUE3XDsGB6DGsUfdEuPhoFCmIX4jXuC2ckYwgLYJ6KepSLOQ6XKUjDl@j4AXvi9jEz2VofRGxMmAkNsx52yMFBLJ8hEOIvZHTENg@OcTQjwNywRvqcnK8/mCIOLz9bii@iUPcUTi6I2JcgAj4uJbULp5/vidtfilEG6VE@Za06ZxSUMTXlueD8SILMCydDwwyRfLILZQLdno43vfmAlLuySD1WOYnUntq5kVyM0ATlHhi1j1C3Atb3TykELlnXqt8kkosqxFqpq9@uJIElSgYgXiW2r0wVQgauFKB567hi8F1ZjeOK0koRGz6nRU5AspzLKfd7cCuQPfMnON9vfMKyjnZLapbTKpB@iq1rvWpa5wsq2gW/rLG5dnCrvoK6@4yniisiOSWc/Z8BwMcbd284ecvYIciiZ3L0netGPuuhZMhwsffR7nUmCf/Jvc6@xrk9@Vxi/TK5@WVNs16L7ytirlDFO1@fsd4iDflNnL8LDF1ATKCm0bJXVzPYy0sCHUGlJ6JeOmIMDt77OyiaLdBXtNSfTxgdS/tYhpzDGEpsx84HuqCblVrAtgF@0JyHjMQ8WDx0@x@WB8XCck80Uhd7sCAaFT0Z@UJa/B4A/WDjOjHImSnb4vyo/FJpszmYoRhvJucj8ONIrr7cfsv@TMyejAjSA6aIxJ9nTdnxI9EuP9NZ0bHultfaG6gd/XTcPssFDGhv2VTrh4Q7o/1BW90wMcDft1AKNquMoiGLVDgYWzMt0bHGKT@IPz4hJHPfIIPt@ZBTDoBxB@NjprwCySew7RvWNT3DWJms0m1QxTt8zqZzDdVJBlCPOy8GM/654gsmY7jNCB3RuWZUk2gY7TJmaxxJX74B6myeDg2jVP9p39gxS9j4XHKcjzO6uPmYHe1A6HQen1d5Tt35L169WDXO9qKie@4q7aJXnbCtDrJG@1KS3LAwLE4tiquDrCd4yFVPKS@dQpdGR445STYscoXK6Dei2rZJxpOqoPIJ4yEJ2AZANxug8ZrNFX8MIdzg@sHBAI74c8sBCs26OGmwUam2RjnXhE7c3gGYpR3GzLfAcIMGvTR@abi2OpITWLEZEOHW0/BY46TMCRPYgmTB4a6B7GPoUmoiUvlWgls@jJGO6enUqUz6AJxtB1RiIOfsabVI2hDcOhT7g0T6sZbnyoGCXTwomnoI2bgEQAdBb@nzujLupAUct4NFJNW3IpJHVryoNI4YiVVyJGwt0UPR/Gw/04kICwbCfBPsBZxf4dtIrtYKq1NpegTa1qm1mTwhjm5iIKP8yf9mng419fXaXhLPJJJX1zTeMq6j3lrPOj8LyD7Qys/kkk0j/Z1ZcSkG4UOmGYbK6upXBHHWlrHIDbE1oKH6Pg0dnXYxw@Z4sIA7MfduLp6reosg9X4TrMHAHjsDKBIgWDfUjo9xQUMZ4oMk/Gd0UXj64kd/eMg09Qnfdq4b4KNR9S4M40xeYyNdnCJXgWJKbxFv6BGQGrB7TkueTbNPiuCo6U2Bh3qDHBflhsDd0cpsQZGUCKVcCPyHJ5FeELWMUvL0I6x8Ze986twPZGpsXNo5jXmTlBIpQCVApp@mee@5MbHngPBfDM60GHzWQ3oEZZZXQxGuZUAoLEPC3M4m9s9afLcBWmZuwdotaEE@eJiNwSL2BcnPT64pmSZ@daUgEjA86aQMekIrGTStYyEqvhJWvdlPcRDyWoU5u6xiYj3esseOdz1C22@@mSNzgRjdIgnkTNSclfVyyV27wLiGhDUcHBlSTzkrhxADdPCuZnxihQgveSOwh5D68tA5iuQVHHIZtgv@YrBF3jXuLVLqCDTwXLNncMC/3Kq5FKDf8Haq//xZNYzXpsLVPBF@h72HRPqtNTkEzE0SyImmCbyip2X4BHiDo5LdPFhzg/kMckNwppIRtOYZ1DlGeU2VxAWqHPGqUuJsSHroPWdD59ibCRe8QD1AD8jORUbleWSd6iyagx6dzgYifEog34Mge@ZCtK@FMC7GNFZPHGvdUMvQWIdBXmABAV6nbv@aNq4S8WYfF@ilJv0mSou4kGPmOX9uWuxLgzEVzyHoQj913g3UfyuJcV4ejhlQA7ZdaRrsXFqnIherocj8yo8jI1AdDDcj1QRow50C@M8vY58QXRGiZinEQIG7bB1Becd60i7sHsCGasPyzBAqo/KaMPj53@hwsubBR0gg/BFBoDxOALCCJW5yi6FE5lB9A2jUQyHQd1k@KCPJwd78WfCsfYIP4/vx38/PiSP6FAfxuqjiLsuBWLUR8tEAm95yv1McSl7v0F5Z/I7Vd4ZenjlfYAeXnln6fmTyutZjN9TQaCLoQeOcXDI/hxG1ADteXI7xXOGnqlxD7X5YTr2oI9fw5mKTR82mI1t9vumjWdwz88BT3NOJijc5w9pPudpFMENA@QkNx/J@RQ0PTys3g7wJm6ZqC@GyY3fHOT9F@iTOrdtiz6aPBBzgSz63mt86h0SiIiuxO/likSvfJgUl6lcnQC17YrWF5eZL6mSl3EqKB@DMYrslT7C@KsPh6/otHwRcuNGQUJF2LwoA9Q7MN50FPSbH0VQXcjHyVhIdTY3lluJGFusrnQ1IRI70i4fJY21bsk311Qn6Qzs6tMnvHGsZ@8dRl0G55VBlt5Q1O2lYSi22yZr2wZfiM0OhXUKtz2BCu90LXPQ6TI8KAp1QITlS8rbJmr3qF2CVo8fmhzgWTVFd1lceFx8z36cZKd9BoN82j@PLffNIdtAxb8xQlsytwWEfd2EWGG1sODqTgtjk/YCSXoPuMYNfdziME6e6syXgU3kB8jCG7TEQfJHxE5zEnY7sbjsaSCS4jhqr@@gZq3xImDxx9H6OA0zjogagHvGFykrCx7o/MxyNvbllnLnz@4esMq83KbmZpK2oU5nsqGiqS/1SOa4FXHadgPZwdQxN5vq76D@vFT57DWM@7/CmpCoy5UxglNhkIuLo0HZwa15PTx9HE/W4JwKI3BAuW9aODYcxeZivkF7HLUu5QbGXjRURrhoQmSnC@PZa1xoNDc2zbh1Fagq2jqAiCAHpFrxuTOcL8Mvj2HsNzQc9SLzAbBNqhyeO8uzYTZxltmNPEsJy2yqastGlVVBXqF8hnF7g2iu7ixhS1M6OEKEkboret3skD2aRotdrcl3ZWwcYlYs9fNAs/hgG3OTgLqkdT/AChtdtXlFsPjNnTH2uGbEgWyGEzfbzP48UCw0OZgWi4bsgJDxvKc5EitxpvUoIaBKE8DEeeVZJcQHjOonHgU5xVauvQ5NNa7Mo8U6@IWJkC2@HSFsRkhbv@0HrSYJBvLKM8hA96yLHbqaTXh8w@8Yaw90lMVmP4FhKAknC@t/Q8WysVjmhxhOFNP3MgHEBetkqA@jWIZieRjC1I2LnphLmq@DF2agMakHgOMc2htj@ejrEQ1IOUG3iekd2hQ0tl9AMNnPw8hvtgvTxrUWliqGEBgnFYlRIrNoqSuexWqYRtyPmYPNIgY4BIs8tf7K/y/VH0MFyEDZAwIGt7@jhbGpoLGSsi5Gn9DSqZTIyKIoIAd6A91RDNUc2Prod80IgQX6oKTQncFrRK8fxOukOo7DMD46S@LHANhu8oCWu@HaBByog/BO7xUxRDoRogYrrmeKfpbpYhuMHXM/LYPTROETDNsTYdg5umsCpkLwyAS09OAyAYf2eMX4sgEQnbRdzHASFM9dYKc0nQEJ0a6JiytwTekA7UG4xsPCLWJUJSiwsSyI3OyrFk8MuG1kDpjbPwO/jo/6BAE5PmtTg0RF10f4UTZjsZDveUcCeBC3DxUuOeyovjggfiHjAE62I8i32701VGGjwM6Nz27h5yIxBUoWnohb43vgxgn@5NT4LBzafDFJxD0VL4XHCkBj81nJ@Dr78KIY30fcgf7U@idSmV1blwvLGUqs7ceZBFpVMWuWcwewWokWWoS1Mq7UWMMdFtAuAfRcqy2Wca6Fr9og2xnW4g0wiKpYzS4UCepLQ4ZxLKJTS2sR2WAMh2Zv7yhzmwH6MqbKFWhj0GvgkTRtope3TZPmPdBIDiDhMeoIpTzeeqmRhNOi/097z7bcRnLds/AVraF2MSDuvEgUweFSEqldJpLIkJTXLoiLxWVAjgQCMGYgAkthK849lVSqHG/s2LGdysVOKnlNUnZclTzkff0P/gL/gXMu3T09gxmS0q7XldRqayVM9@nTt9Pd53SfC9DzM1T1pPvjTk6vLa6K5BIUfgBQ3yPhCSrbRPeXcmDwO9Rs0qPTteUnXoUs4bDgd10mopsS6Y9@LmvpWHmu1yLfUi2OsXoJxlx4eRYzCcMLr8BQcTofjF7wyxFeu9HOHzQ9uvfGt0BWWMZC6kYPH/n9MI9fMtTlXBjWhNYzHiynzeDqS15FTQFsij026GHDqXCA@Q2vFiota23kCtMWbGFtvoEqyyzUjOKyMoQUbeyaeNSbK98hsm1QxTTdkmPtmEuB51peZbJd26jXldxVhDYkpKQIhFYtx@t3eSWp6igSGoLixrOMQ43POwqsJs2dimbKDMV/bqcaPkkrbn@zolYj04fjMHWEdWgl4bahqruozBtYnywy/BTa1dEBHN5s3GjH4OvUmphI/S6ytJqwhteNmPwtuMd1ZElv3Ji@zujQWGg18fBO3iJqlsuA5A6tDLjEtBGT8tTG2OWln2CqIpU8OdwBHO8CgylI8w34NC/D/SCnn@vlAvWDkh8Q7RgnfZF3H6DvpHXX7PkD6cqMDlYu5NN74eu9xKgVyNXLddcad7Ep@NIPZUIDlXnrlJtdveWQai4/@PNIETjpHY4RB6//nKEtqBzqs9UKQJHJinzhlwXr6k4c0Us16q68I@MeiMWGrFb2Qbkwwk7Qg7fhzoakqndH7gn8c@Bhizp@Fvkl/fJdymzzZeL@3u6To52DxsHOV3YODneoJCnya4Pi8bBMN2X@OTr37ku8WT/iECfz/siDcxxPHIqzhBL4YXsQBOIhiLsuiOMvmlCyOXYzqW/uS4/S85767midyx8xM0/G96Rp7HtoIjRGVSXo3zkL4Pw8bPs5Jn44A8khFWq99tCTAceFyuCeCZs55@D@iSupNaAQtwQhLRvwSBl0g3PkAKU0EX1jhpOm14HV7Jakjq2CxiuH0F@CdoiADADko9bttERhtM21CgPvAs@JbCS2lUPiguz9oCL2udptqlZsc7@Qh2z2Bv2TjPSeYLSAODc4tAoYpHtdDTEZBUEVqLeAngJxpLlH3KEyygflaqlS/vxcGoSP2L8hbwVvYJL/hnbe83b6ifGTksz2VQwAg8eZxWzoImGTEi3okqM1RQ3qYhUtyYrezJw83Zpcol/@DVuQpxiQy9atfDFG45@vPfe1zaw/s4@FL94MJ5GAI1Y5inwTVUxnn5/Bzv8Vq5HXMxe5yoriS9OJZNMJGVDtdYwnsotZ0j5GzmN3jy/s8apJX//4SrtbhjOK8WRq14oo2uoINlGl@TAejdREvp4SfUSDPqJW/mtTh0/va4ItQNjdZLXj1@i1YRwR6WjltTThdaCeK1TcTW39WaT9ql5TbR9V2kdT5D3DizRcc7K5URVp2m1evRIRNXC2dGEdXyJ/qWGuzVuUU3njMk4po8uzQ92ZccmY@jtfCiaU1kHeAhkji8NrRUPMSWo1bRIlXKUWUYiXclRO4ZrNj19MbT0cwfCylJyImZf4sq32Io4NBqKiswFtD3LxOYqgDC9j01BGp0bNRVplcqHN2YToF/j/L9ZWmgTZwONLI6vfoJHVl1YjX1qNfGk1cpnVyMLN8tgflVtevwysWU8Uz4H7zyzAgtreE@@/d@9IHL23Ix4@ffDb4mt7T8X7955Ayp7Yf3r/0e4DAf/vPDncEVRA//mKO0KVewFTv@22XbqdX6pUVgRhngtQviIOm2fivUHbfQnEs@E3z7ZO@aPUd4NNLrXz0h1NB/wcNERllkBaTdBdEb81qRsntLhuASWf4Tui8uWJbSRvnj7fLJHtBYVD1wbc/LZHPAjpcdGzkjbaAPgBpAKaJj/Jku40Pq0T09IpCTlw@s9rjyAwhY8Pxb0n2xjpc3v3aHfvyaF4uHcAn/tfQzc7YnsX3cbcf4pZBPh4b3v34e6De5TADaiUBN6tkcH6ZU0oITiNSvtFd4zhwXooFcqviFfvhUymP1BWEb7Ijvuh@54OkBS@u7Oz0xq5aLdv3Tt49yvI1bhfF5aFQS4Nh@rSAuFWBY1GoDYZRbvGztSRtSxWeUM6m4pbmF3L0B0Q/S4IhTxH78SeK6wHeI2ID9IUN5sZNoUaKroJuBGVcgTrCIrAkM0WNgjlJtRGtweqNrxY7aoPLLolHbOiHLmgvLT6hBSDM@722xxGVyUA3bNWN1UbjBgAL4RkAgPgHQwmBM0X7i5ekohVCTEOUPCHhNuc8Pxs@PAcuUY0cJUJ9zkQyJpsE88bTSkGOGp6fZ7HiFkT7w4UI4WK@ASPTnJ6PXXlSipxwP/LNzZ8lQVIC3bBLqxsJVSEz25ADbC3nza7gS9sJ4e3wSCCuH2PNbVOek0Q9@heeIQGSy9RjYCqXXPwz6ZyVK8YTgrEqUSY1lRE26HLbcuD371uOSh5f65G1NujTqPClIz/dGUD7s814E3QAKKiuV@gW6FhQIwtoRl0JSnb/gAoEkQ@8XE0qtGgM267kQJS1rGfex99lJODXAiLGCo@1DqtYYehHvAh5Bx9UJGbCxBiSFPyFF@jeA7taA/Ct@EzVIYYYQM/VIMrazOFB1Wj1MSRlSI/n1Jrq0nGcFfWShTPusF6@xpqn1H0/O2zWR49k7RQTNbSnI/@nFGJAT07jdDNS1egYtE0oJZwcIdMuHd8LPxy/YM1Z3P7/rPixx8WjsvlE94Wmh1@vGClRH5mIZEclofWnSRtQLXSJNKMP25haaXPyLslrnKFDBiXUw@Y761GTefxtep8ep/iZUXTKfHVK4dLFcnehEgII8mEu1tB1FWVBSpzLHISQbh3QmPRs65KKRBOvV9vYVx7nIUajEgf9xFSrzHDqpF@jeHtGh/0YGfJSD6Np1vjz6lY5JKi6I9tzkf5A/u@k9/MlRUULSY9nLbaogsKczUnezXD6aXzag7d9uXoYP@@Prq1S1vHx8NrYdu@FNtrta2YT8fFx5KB6/poP74ELR9ub4QW@l5IR8yH5Dw2TemaOAu3FhTNX1Hjh3NzR2sP0ODZixFVNVKjtnG/hx7ibL4Uh6ZRgZyJJmSIDo@2dw4OhLWDt2zrUBb2vWa/TfaluA0i7pvK0xHbIdNmV9JMkw4TpJknlTJj89JotZct5sTBS9kqJA9SkOOhNwsdtRckk4m0juCThVgINLzmDVGNXLR1F2oP8usS8ayOmlAinDSjg5nEbi7w4cNO9mmTCcetwLyx/8IbambGnUhnXXRVPZqaiBQjjMdB8wRfvpPn733mj9dVPcxguV8fU4dRCb@N/vLFIVQ8xJfiUnQGL5kWNaWks0JUuqDGjszyohz2ZycoHYt9JnlhY1uXzLFsGvPHt4xIdsSfbuE7/1Rmts/kfafa4illw5zQXHjo2dEjCJhMEIPFlkkVUPx4Jo8wGg19TjqaITfX2i1qTV21kqKZSdy1dKC3gINfvR3fHuJVwW57aVXFz6cqPiUiNRlxt@ZrUJmA@fbq6vJVuOO9UMWLnxU3nyHx/TM4G75sGij9qU@qQkC5u08KKj8kgEuGzgEpsGOrBRMrCKxOwpkS6TsdRmb7oC3nI7TFg8bsPT0q4H1RvNacmMTaloydTyQTO4HM9cFYwrqjvGrmRn92eXX3KajbFfXdfP36eLEhEN6Hz37FYTIPBkPcKoERHzXYKyqI5Os@asUFWIKDD2pPv0YMzC0Vx7LO8ea2@IUbbaS5xq1g8AL1@lXkTBnbzMJnqNJZc3jxCi@4XtGVKeehTYAs6xXE1nPWUeHImludASkRdHUoyy1uZTQNtvmXDTP45jqqD1IeAxgPmI4ewOzbWQFyzzreKqhQk9k8pwF/opOKnAS0GqDsodMXOR3tErxhb6rTy5zecTHwnE7dkFjOmzriZXZTQsYjZGYtCUx3tV532qBh19nvcDawMTrpLdkYkC17A516k1NRp0ol1WXZcZh0zEkgSemkBQmFB5MXmLTku@6LBk2yjDYHCLMF0fd6xyWpP/WOLWXHnDThCHgiobzb72RoUijmqUaljoQtdC0rSai@5R2XSIFSbkAok4UTywtpywsLmMCQboS@ZKLiYtQA/Fs2QjbVJF6sub71HCl85PrtsSt2Jijjq9iIiirJMciC2HmyLfYeioO9/Z0oamxxA3kUKqUU9igUs2wYdUct2QJM@GAcnDY4UX3Gc89dzlUo@FsD9QcjA4g/47mqAkJxjMtSXLzqvBJ1OLyHelLsTu5YTrrqse5DqT0Y94OLV5NXNL0T4PRKQALviFkJLwnemRsWuRIlh63Igd7iMCwk8pUN5VYhrIVSqJaJ9M0xkBbXsTWfm0lsGb1/wtTByqRNOgzICdsk7gQDZHnWZXxLGI72aRhwk96yHWHb8YbhoVQqzSXnxR0duNE1I@5GK7tmJfm0Su6GlTCFaTwlH@OIhrXlRGcgXnmvVGXhoYJH/1pc2tGjjb6b5TQaRwwtuwhM5djI5lcJo8@dTPTX3IKTMyii8Ubl6wYvCAzyHu7mDtN4BIzoew5Mbw4KjBfQHBytggggL5M5QCo/j7GR3Mpw6SUUSW5xuB7nm5NSS4guoUhyLWGjo1MRrvXYbLQHwJ1xQBL80QBB0DhfE2cOyGau4rTFKuIFJSmSONPgOm3@J5dQh9qmGQLo8Vj9rB6z6Y3ImsUuhY@OiNkC2XljQHAPIncqeKyZ6dV4unkkiU2jeBzCaFQMGHDGTqqr54I9iUSSztFSi5cVGW3JaODIa8mjEbacYwOUSCgFtBgF5VUTwgIoghAXhyeLAcorMQqaTwY1iJ/gTayxthqrUYPmk0GN9TGHtZiENQqaj4PO7Wu0UUbHXjO0i/blk5dL4WNNdEZV7sRtjwM@aZTTClhDASwPk9GS0B3vxAveESGjRb9K0B4k2pU16RFbpYGAv3pHsz5UQLHaZhNktSFC3C0MXspLqJivo0z2LWTMNfMYgecQ1/g@boDWCcKcBsEemGRDFJMhBRp1iilWzBwaLjUJRI2MkYQlFi7gc4bcb33hgsUdjvxuFazczOJm1SK7KPRJJUv5aGNDjUUpGDQ8kfinJhtPOAZDEcVRCpMu@RPBMQ50Kl5xFHqDNl92FhBXTQlrdUhHAZwedmI48DVlvi@qIKA5vrod@KAyjwObkBeXdcrEoYSqeRyL18ahBLZ5HMXrt4PkqaS@vHVtHCwIJuEoXxsHUuD8mFoLF4Bgxn9bSaQWGQ80i5KpzUIrShoaZzPy1Yr3RYmqAu0FCUMEfhL7SmqHZMxNWu8ZYtC1xgOFjvnxsD1eSZtwFNPOXeEL5iqWzM2tFxZuKZVvYI2VVxO3/KADB0Gp29PrO2Hxx0T02CWJREj3HijElNqnIxCRcDZLUvpQDAjhhPY3Gqia1WjQzdD@wd67B/ceN57ce4xC1ALvUXh9g9oypK5TKS1hPHu@bWmQTpEjUNUCu5GhfdjIo/ZJNDt0ilDkWCy1cGHAzSxmoLAmh@6LSn33XDyELApaP4cTIUv6bgamx6Y26E3dKr60ciGkeYKpXkl5bRNaQjBMJ7IlBGMkZwxhi8s/67OGyrP@s4ABW6LONpn@sdneZ2i4ZBQUovjyWfAVd9RCXZKidlrKs4gq@Ci7kXMqVLmQN@ghBmMCf1Uui/vKKa60X2v22ujydtwlx7dnXq951uo0S8PTYabrO9I9jZ3t@ujkMoPKVLtHOweHjX2M07XzgCwn8E@N8o52H@/sPT3CnEPIWpbJOwcHewcNUlA/eLp/hB5DY0mWCSixhGAyIQL0ZO@9e48MGP62ZCPZIMQHeRP@ka58CsIbNib095TMPAqsCtGgIDxkpoJFKa0gAu/MHYxV8Db0P6EO@AJanuCjDNSlohqTQxobrz9lXujrdGZAUTtG42FAoKQBb8dGIhctwTBn/gkWIF9EPvDtpE1f4htlzENDvsHQjpVFAxkslpH2XV2fVgcuk8Npv20rdNKRZ@HC7QMkvjZlx0G3uJad5dCr5JCUhuKFs2U4OcrkHDWbXFKOoNRKzxhBjMxr11pGGbwDFFmU0CSElilUgF8QayKf93IXGTNAlMyCXZXjR10Iw4Y@CiPj19ww5ojdmrKeL9SPBKJ/SQscTSP8uW8@ShGByfcpMuaoo@W5HjP6V3WWb5htPTs2vU@Fdt0l1B55AA2@F9js6IV89oV0J5@7ZAMamBGf8WgeoJdvY7LDVCHTuB/UYKCC0VSwBaEf6OGCnh/j3xPp2rWNCjQ2EFzOhLUszmV3lGgk5AcMQGKetWmth25s2CxBKw4zxIYJUU2C@MCEWEqCeGlCLCdBfPoJg3hdO59Xk7cpllZXWZs5Mp8Jxf9NFy8WFeyGUoUOCwM@s7g6jRnJDuOQ0HkHzUHNMxuQmy27fWnLoqg//XfAbeKSpYpUCTf8kmZfgvnnv2et8w3dNUbpr7mHxgaFzIl88mITZrwvfCBJXDVJ2pLGsf3kEmyWpWYxuex3Q4r4IIVoPv1pBCaZbL6t5l3o8VMvXDfCstXQqiGO4D/mETivg6DB5dX6Im@jbMCL2UvrGovqQYiAQZZNkKU4SFKVry6tsmLiqyZWWTVBKtep8tOfyTrl@ZUA8UMNQXutHMxE0P@KLDRSzYdCSaA@Q6JNzX746psKfhJtg1ksCXw/xE5Fji9v98@/EW93WDIR/vcTiZMKmPSlpj1x4P/hujiWU3F8yCiKxdRxyzJEPp8K8emPwnbw8MaX2WWL5Od/eHXpSnrp3w1Lh8f8pjq4mWtQyOJboFYPimZS0brGxvMHA6BTElpjHKN6zRlLDs9iaTAW7UBVZ0uLs2j2ksqeJmYv6@wY8hkzWIpLQv96xBhtcIRBYo3C32TlywyXytx0TK4txx0yuV1m1qWBOYyN5nGkKY7B9GzGBI7FiJAxj1rm5iSzN8sQF1xLFH785qh52m9igFZ/0C/JCCDeoLxzNnju4UE1KqObi9JzP00a@iysNSEgOc5B8fUeKlRAU6VTEdb9ZrkdAZvt9vhs3MM3NEfKVegYqVxGl3EkCPbHZ77EiSfu/bHXgx44yKmFLCKIeUNoJZ3CwEpfq/pY1UnVzldZLrPeeInc0FESta098oYBVebMywLo8okYVKjC2zBgFQuPBuoXhIhd0TqyP4@8vmsb8BjF1SsYCeQXIe9wqRpRRnxMDBwF1AB5Mj6LYLiQM066MQ7nlHy0@LErhSUcORfpRoxcjBCirSM8XyxJH3TkWgaRSAuiURTLUmElx6NEiPaBPM@iECuFpQpWNMQsclFEnqG1ZnmzS26LyKiVcBA2DU2zABxhiF6O62YFegcZul2O9cu//eTvrNxFuazSKKaO12@CzEARSUKs@Hk02FffBnqUT6StYgz334e4GXXHbXtnTYxQExiogbhSMMMEIuYLIDR0WjXowX4zOLENXzCqQiSscvne9rY4eu9g7320huJLBKKCWHEkgnVh5XnYqWQkXyoGI4ikhHmYx7JiBFKNmIfSvUIw3WNyr9O1DQ0sGK1v/jGNFt3lD1DTnddlDCFmW@zUB@8JUbfWRKsnQlEwzsM3/4gxD4asPZuMeDC0JGHCz6ELxK@uIu25fjFEcn2/@P6fUXXSogR4PrxXOTOrTmP6KbcuL2SJZovV49ReRaqhQUhFfOUQfevHhMznIN1qI8zcMHdFjSS52z/8K0E48PEBZs8oKSJ48lci@jYj0q8HNHKp@IpX4vsO4@t49ApgImpNo118DOdkaYRGQ7aRXL5i@H7xfdligPcCfDO5pI7FSHMziZPxr@bMUlk5HWnza@BPneEfmEilmWsaRj6oEvF88rNwmZrdZNfJTN83jNUZa1pihz/5zyTqIx1zWD3oAZzRmlOVuFZS2vwXf6nxTzI3JlcQzC//9ns/Cvs4Se3ZJLU/3wtX02S@F5O0tt@IbUlfxSPDyk9Sp@Kn0WoiK3fiGJ9pCH6SNu6T6GBP0pY8kL5e9JMrln0akm8rJHrBT65c8mm4vqNwJS72eLdSlvskdZkr7CkLPYZ/MaWZsBj/xVyMk8tmPnXNp5PF3xByZPjQeHRuWsplyeFUiLXdEFX6Fz3z4r@b8daYux9etYWMiwMcFaBDqSlCewg12TBX/kU8pvyM@ZowtSqdLageGbVUZS0gmjR7fkJVjvO51bWEQwfiXkItm29WSWZWLvddNrofDzsoddD73RlJHiN6/sPgAck74zdoLoHbBnGFrW3IPUGdmnxMLzj@HPkgOvI5pEQN9ADdAXGD/t3Q3S1WOYXkjRtxLL0Bs0Q36DodRaFUQURKEvnqcaJQwXJq4kL4J70DsXTVYukKB0v2kfzIhjlXbt7f@pHekfQoDaLYYyjzV@P8RzkNpGJEb@XksUPydOmonciXFqSiqeoISD26/9ncLWLVpfOSBlga5u/@iT7oXB91WTvQHzR5JY//GBwTByb1BDT2T/5JCOzcYrhlpNb8p2rifd6h0irHk@wa9aRU8@M/sJC0kweJs2tXC1kSY6qMJXafiKeHOwdi7@nR/tMjvJAxHSNqGTxd0GOxm/dlEmCjlwRzsmwNxPwlFmeNPCYvr@Dll3LU/T//Hnaf0eYdq2IZw3RpuR9EylVVuUvGiKbi2iMkx2euPF9aQOu4btlbx1mTIwQC9G4/wPXqu/BDgvHFBDt8lmcbkz@bTJtSt6yY8Vxj6j/PbhmXMemXCXjU4QQ4VYHz51S@pIwvhjLoymqKr3dO0mse44deKJefBPpFU1DkZjP5wvf8/LzUxfBU45FXcn10T@SjY7jy8ASYhf6ALjXRbTYQntcG2RadF47bL8JfxXaz/7Lpo4LMOxNUiXbuvj3lfzNpd8TDkzMOxfGm98RC0G1vYVpoFwBZodV@Ueied2oygw2DtcIJJyL3M1IfZ7765Q27GmIQ4D27zmr1XrQHPeJ2rVYPDjIrrJp7qCCn6lN@Dz02jFGXyFPp/VQQ02yzIoXARwPKgZ/AVSnrYm9Snx5Hik908Yg2i88RMS9FygrBmM96HBQ2YML5k7BSVW19Ip3FaxMyfH1ApRAFiWimCiZiEY45E1aK38QXKkxDyGkkDS1/2g6VVuPNXzCPjiIMoIkhDLhrl@sfPKs/O@777vnicb58UkBHRwjdkmaNNKbks4d/4@j3XvaGAz@S1Hf9gBVcKiqpfSqpgWmFFV/kWMU0bqBZWuHGCwcNtQMdysQt@l5ge9JMlbRxTul526pb4Rhzw@qyMTjSnlIykGn48GSY2puIjg1EmK67pCLxJelCWe@P0J@Wgi3CmKMDmP4UzQgxUEN0qcgYpmIWbRW@lnECDDv7wI11ReXDVNRjWUY3Z3L@zebffO3md2FdJLeeCJY3xZjS2MSFDdeVy4U9Ym46xrxCC8qLzR66/LN2@uSeRikO5mqLZWWawvVgF2TQWWPy29LxBL@k9qUWCtY1RdlXTB1elrwu1JBqTZPwFZ7yFSHI8ryBcASRhGKuLDYxi4GkyxsHPYslFTs3GjmhRk64CENPUhp5LIthIE/TbcMxOm1rwnkE@Kqs0UtiofCbLzE@FbsiWizrOsM9h6hAWRjChCKdtY8Ta68bjTY2rRgCJMQ5BB232xz3gvVMfMOrFvWX3qN4KNUexV@SDHivAAKjLbjGSmW2JjL5YoFX6R65vYRf9YxVLVQKVfqvwv9bBZWo/q/OJ1aikNVoYqUQ@@/XkniMI5ssFlUrK7ghZ361IIbT4HTQX8osCH1mCzqz0R8hv6A@9/l92O97w6EbUJgjceL28XEbA796A7yxQOdfGFcHfr9wyb/IukIu@Cm28dxvIKKGRFQaToV1a8uCcT8bDkaB@KjntdRvjFF@e0V9@VMf3Uj5rks8kA9MkHzmRn3fo9F0N9jr471EGT0mBwP@3eoNWuUzEOXdEbly9GHNA4Q3KI3G/TK5m3L7HXwWJzOE5gto2ilUB13rNACsgd2yc0h5vovuKa1nk27XIuctbq9z6CLjhrdHQkdS2e0Q39H0Ty3c1hbEE2DC1tndivJhor100Yi7Iisf44o9judMGgNZI9IXarxjLEvSzLBQKVq@15PrP6tED9BQysoRW2bn6EQcBCG8UuWUBVgxJFIC@4hB@pgxxrMi7BGGCHXRskQ2Ii@ETKB2hJ@y0jCBKpLns1cA9hB7paxoXRumlXnG6jq698S7Mqea0zuFh3ZS1bV1jM1BPcEBxWmST8PVNcwhB5W@wIhz7JvG7EfekS0BQJ4QCoQIPPYIPTK0npMSKV7WweGB9FdSeXg90UKXaD2K8YL3V333hKKkiPOWx6FgOp5PAFiyfPKRN5RDVIiQamt8Aqw2rQWKrOL5/thdvbO2Qg2iuEYKtDNoR0CXyoAZXcuWqXGnwVlP9@JucCp67ku3x/7fuNkU@4UXJdGZLbdPvG6@nSPSgaGM9BRGwb5b4LTtnYeP7h3tbBdEsbqK4GygqmFtY3A5O0/5ZMAhyQiL8PIttW6vMJHbfiG7Vc7mZNO3zGHPmw1WCGDPGqEcN7SzDhWTN3OMGESmDu5VBR1vUcd2Q11tXG7YlPEIoxZYanDVyl9YsJCksa4FJMHI5ghlcuGhAV@w8cwBpe4VMAJyd2ugEIahhIhyrY2bxaJeU@v0qwgba7G4yXbm1gOQw1@I7MG4H9lts7R2miILmxx6y@Ot7WaW9oWSVROnTvYtP1tD7lxzTi/tce5Chfjrd7EVNg/c0eD@VM2fPVZaKzAguXr1OJeTCdn/@W8Q@2ahWUDPDnIXyF9/5CiXsCXe1HfYg6ad5dtgKPZRKXAnwQPaXAMnqOkCrUFnWqKQpJ0HcPZ27I/MOoZ27oK0m9uOs5y7gCpHQ7RDGcJm6B4BxlwN07qRtFDkePasj25xF1H@@urjR@/BlB@gfyk/qH9wvHirXMhm4YgnDSQHI32I7b3H@3iTMMqV6Ebh4WhwJsdl1NSVlPBhHy2HqfUFC7tWxlUIO@eJG8je@/enR82TJ80zkJibMATRC5ymqfWDYe5Rl98cI8eKTq6VuzhxCOp05HZrzAnNfOelfZKrBfDPqVnFKlThLC0R9gAKOehAIDbqXh9O6/eOHj9yshtNgVidhFWRzbc0cQChEMHYmEQCbYR0MJwuUlXAdptEMPAnn7U2o33ZKDc3s7XZLLU9jwbNDnv8yoYE3LHHBUlxI2d@SmujkAqmQ9fBBD7a3t05sgpQFmVfTKQYR1PatNgZsaPqYHLDnYKOwOkhwjjOyttvUxoWGfuOs1Sp5FA9ZAbYyAcEoOWFNarNRk2nY@uBbA69El2duxOui5iTpdJSudn3z4EdLVdvV@4uV94ZjPDdoOP67bd92EKcJoaU9YLp22jIT@pkJ4Ne9@2u18MHq5sri2t73v3f@erdw9vbdrv1W8BDWs/9AT7gj4ZmA0bNc6n9B3vsqM3URY3oA852szxsvhiUVzqV9lplrXqn495Zddcqy2vtVXf5buvu3bvt7spaq3P3TvPOartVRrfRVKR0RsqDFpM/Vtu9XrVpjNnaUuVut1ut3r7TWb3bvbtUWV5eaa2tdiorK921anN5@XZnaa11t3U51xa2JwMbrNp38eyI78BvpTN3mbm9XZbO/S8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0,_String os4721en _e25 $91or 70939597cr=B+R_u8"?!"3&&1ca g570rt Unuxf28t t;ince =1;#0:60Num
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<#<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW<<[|]
>x=1;f z t=z+t;y#a=f 0b1204;x#a=174;instance Num();b1204=50+78*length (show(toEnum 0::   (Num a,Enum a)=>a));(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on Laikoni's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156352):

```hs
instance Num()
main=print(toEnum 0::(Num a,Enum a)=>a)
```

Let `expr` be `toEnum 0::(Num a,Enum a)=>a`. Then `show(expr)` can be used to separate ExtendedDefaultRules like this:

```hs
b1204=50+78*length(show(expr))
```

Which is equivalent to `b1204 = length(show(expr))==1 ? 128 : 206` in this situation.

The code in polyglot:

```hs
>x=1;f z t=z+t;y#a=f 0b1204;x#a=174;instance Num();b1204=50+78*length (show(toEnum 0::   (Num a,Enum a)=>a));(!)=seq
```

`f` is used instead of `(+)` to get rid of parens because now it is shorter (taking Prelude into account).

I ran out of `w`s, so used one from Prolog code. Prolog was moved up to line 175.

Test all ghc answers [on TIO](https://tio.run/##zTpdk@PGcc@G8yOGwOpAEATxQYIEiQ/u5@l0vjuu9vaykkkuFyRBLm5JgkeAt@RyeSXJKcWK8xJZUcl27DvJSSUProorlQe77FSqrHeVf8P6KaVKlf6B0j3gcvfu9pw7Oa5KD2amu6enp@cDg54hm254@PXXLTciDulkeochMxoPuoctIrWGwys40lt3vK4b@Q@9W37kjdxeeKXQm2M39N8cB5F3dfltt@u3bkDbV5auu4PuthuB/sHV1df9gTua/lELtiaRN2h77U2v44570c64d27K119zap4QtpzPJgOxrCumyOuqyRPCEW6VsEROsSN2VtuUHhKvo@UfSFW3k3lQ3z7a3n5LqCVJkfDcRoVVc@w@4C8JBaK9AMg3B45LyQwnp9RrBVk@ODhgD5BbdTJOpr4QEaoSX68mC4Q4hUIqnTdS6VW@ccksIalpwl3i@zKp@cOw3YYYHHIISS6Gcpm2xcH4cDGC@TnvwphYZMHlXlHuoatzpFZw3ZSY01YHZkZTtM9/lZinZ9sN6/N3@7KXwKyC2Qfz24jfVfXXEonX1tdzuTQMZIxvf3f77bW1tdxmWt@u6uWcpCSs3/1HIqFpliYn6mGo1vnq0VuspuTYzOef8dvbbzbCEAaiiJAlKqCYGhBVouvkiJwAHHUIPhQ/aV/CXcSbnRPSCtr@oGuPo45BeF7P8nf3@aunLUFUp1z4/UeVB1zEOZq8N4I84h5weYOLUUCAyp5TDzmHs1AsP@emsm3bgBZ@/69Q37kJerBkakHi6Oe68lPOkWxa5ZRz8oComgbt/tc77zCcM@FOOFVVuSkNDcQBjGvqNYKIzBYMNghWgaD2Ti7BRS9kVdVq5/N5abpxapfsQ9AN80qCS7zlvC9XFVmsBoq8rJwDyRbCF//@xSdffETDJzT@huFINp9YPdgkxCMihVJp9bl5uPUMvZORADLLt4NDUlr0jDPsdCO2armEuUvIM@OwTMliSJb0K8oxXCvo971BRHAfqj81GTVONXKV1clLA7kw@nxsuYshXTZOnuWdT8aSIOd7AXkVOYZ7ZNs7EYbbTQzbIQYy@SaAy6EMkIBAH4AliWmCchZsKvI8JP6E3Zfhqly1Xr8xwPDgkIYRhuYDDLdOMDyIMOy2MOw8wLB7goE81xuGsyyLE8UdUSSLRfsycA9iJtNYUMvFC@r@T4HkKvnKKgPvRF2U5vNqZn8imubisZwlalKIMTCrPpcka98RxSo1r@os7LSkugO2xibTZN8CxaJVtaxMw3Ecqb7vVK2nKy3qra6K@KKuQkWnXq0y3AznwsYkhUkrxFRjWZmSuK3Dd7oIGKEozRYMKCcxzXAH1kFSLItlpac8VNQj9eh2ULl4KpUJFPgT5X4wUg6VQ7UNOyVRvHvKVJlOlH5QUduAehCUPqC@0pkoXWWgDFR1OnlK1YuffiWIblcC0BZAzWiiRKhY6UDerVRug74OtH0fgq8oygSMnCgP4VF6uG8rCDTfbwg1pkrYAw@8gozKZxQ@k@d5v67nhw/YNN@oVfm6yclhrSabw5EPu4uWM4k38aP5vNHYurPZaMi4gqwVcVWUVgFsR7QWWZlzzHKtJOHMxSsv0@Bkq1xzshLieRGmRwOeJYuvCBcqIXcSNYY/3tvbw7h3/PA4xihCsdre3rIUExlZFKMsABCVr6z/FEIOgz/X0678/3pu3yPJal0gJDmbW0kKAgZBmM1n80XqCMnkgkhaEJABNFaZzR1EqdAMsGpSqAvzecyDNClYsUIH27AcWvlCEF5VLm61xpuEuPZKki6/DqnVJooimE3geC0YOGlAVtzTY3ToBbPlhh5ZaVbVOvEHRE0JVETPmWZugRcM0zQWuJrPm2ZqKaUAsUBByAvdlokL3eSGAtoQL/@k4g7axHvo9pJ8su11/IHXLg@HwrVralE5PV2yGo22P2o0kJ89Pa3Bm8RXlbptF3XgKMbpKbx@vBCMkneCgUdQZzEYEVXWLtQfuiEcbkbJE3@YrvF4iAlrvIDlmqKgMNYnumXlc46TzwGeNwTBZFdm1NRkVyyqwnxFZuNuEHaF5xZFqlEQKHfOYznhLFJ2YIWHCGQ25@hok5wuJJtTT1gy1GIx5pBcPmmIxUWwEwKxZCdFFqFazYq5VCG1Wq9ffLlwmzBnrq3O7ZlbGox7vbnZCgZh0PMyvaBL3GvXskUYF0Mxa0yjsbm2u9Zo2CzLwlELdl@CTLrhMKEXwWzw1eE4ColerFexJ/Uaz5fM1XhiDZ1wvLmQk3jYuohRpB3mwpDxOzBLZEK1xrGkprRsQtYnr@W3FHC8T1MI1WrV0AwxBVtbqlis1@uUe5qgdar9Sacu9V1/YEtVNa/XJXRd7k86KW5I1EKWSzFDMgiOSUEh7aDXc0ck6HQSwIR5JU3PG5DQ6/XgKECCcUSOg1Gvfey3PdC@fWttY2s3rVmgUru@tpHW7t5b51Qk9QuaFmeR3tla26zcgwrbt7bW7m69/sZfbt3bBn4I30cYLID@tuuNvYZ3PB4fI93wKGz4oXv/vjscNoYAk87Zk/fPnvzV2acfnn36/tmnn3z1@JP3If4LxA/j/MNfFHVMv3r8d/909rNPgfkbiL@G@KuvHv/onThS@rcQ//MS77eLeEkujjCUoO0HXz3@6LOvHv/tjyH@dBF//Gw8@/jf4ud3i4Dop2cf/xaTBfH@h2fvfXT23rtn731w9t73QPmXv3yCz0e//PLXT/D5559/@cu///IH/0iRn8TIf//0F3H6h3ff/8N7P/zDu49fkL7/R9PHL8F//GfgvLydL6PnZfr1qpzH38ieP2U0LlqhC@yTvzn70fdh5X4cU38NFDzLog@WxLJEpIc6SbxgfkDIqQx@k7J6uhQFlf@AXGCT06e1Ua5yzv3q8Q8/Q/ZTst@/rEFRn5ddQeFlax@A7M@Whl2W/eDsyTtnn33v7MlPzp78ADc0KVdMr6Ul9X@5FwJB/SXkUDD/MnIgqMLpxCIJkmA0QBIW3mMwqnhwAEOaAAz87xSjZ4HCc8yzUK87CLWq7NTkmhNDHeiM7CAnI9dkLM/I6NGrDlUGVokMtAznoVR8ESHi/QPECZMrAoVXEyJ8gsS4SISidZHYti0yExvKqCiQWGdCHAMPXXjmsEEvVorrpBsGeLVksk61QE1b3CGNlD2JK4rIcKgGggYha4dVNVY07E1o0J5sEtSFykXmAPID2zHsiYPqHlETQIe4Dk2ClI3WTZxHQNtUJ8gzk81HYIphi6JjAMemXaWtpRu0TVWnnaN9FwntN/LhAAxZeZWQ11jVYOOzH8wFWUhjKl5Il@kVSBnKa2Jq0R36nKM0prA@TPSEjk/Mi8vLyKb1FwKgV5IymQyBKElozSoUT2JVIm0WMjHWACMnLq6Qlgz6mRYZkc6vSAloH2x4ObCcSwSqw@6srKwAZjlslq3AUYKMjkph5I4ieAupk1QibL7IIttDl2xlmx42UpspSFV4thIhsxyOFLPCoy/Ak/M2JDEb5AKOWn/eNdqXFLVcpHIMd8GPHVz0BSLwTHNEYJLosBCBnlW94RDy22F3PZiAE5pm2bSaj2@VhcVR9u2gVLIfqbkCAzmlx6TlopuBDiZMw6E38jL4luGAOjOJvnGIgr@SZxyHVMYR@FREZZy7W7tQYbdCVE3JEPBcZ7mCltNzupbN5/WCpubyxVxeN7KwxeUVXdPUYi5XNIqFOTVpFbaKdCnV1C3n28/BX3z7Kriai8A4b5FJhkhzxplIkqxRi21VL5hTG@ygLMahnljso09nEsEu1ppe1x/MWkHbA7OYmYTL9FsAhPkWQ74FLABQGwzBGfP7wwAm/42KiZqITUbjQRJG4240YlUdFoLA1GAhxNqY4bPA4MRdg93mmhqjev4CVRDddY88cgfagGkYkFtwSiBRQHaDIEIfcN1rMRa4@27r0HMYZhs7UoVBrTNbsAiqdcaSl6VXa9o4dEeoaWMUgI/7zWXW3cFRXLTph9HIb0XLohtuvw@nkL4fHb5A4t6w7w9COKr82TRs9ZtgIF50xgLrkIx6QXCVQIHc235BL28HowGMRBQMYDC8sBWL77zx@o3dS/nu1trGDSZP1it3Np/J9IWQTm5tXd9dkoW49LyqvlTx9tatW8@SiwzPKQmiF9Jp2B8hwTxNgeaZlf1zETXz4i@vkm7AWqXniRBeVhXWdMPTdLJSVOFoWFCK2aJeLLRG9rq40xgbbDnBZuEs2nJJVy8osPTvDcaTjmbA/mP6g5YHr5jJKaW8cmfcZ2C4PFJU4QhDokM/ZG7AwaY/bh0SPyR@xIy8NhxyjgcED7PN3tgj4yF5IRMyZCE68ruH0OBxcC7ANF2XQHxVgPreZYj@OCOK26C850p6V4jjD2h@hyhMhl6CaUVDN4pZzUgbRSOnw/lPT6taWi0YhaKSVhXVUPOGXlTTRq6YzcHWCKUw@gwHW4jfkWXY@VWWpTmMdW/c9qwwavtB5tBhuPgOAT63SVcgnLtkjA3CZo2aAvVYpgWvMvHtBKvlCLiZWZWAQpe0CHf9@oZy/TrLriOBV30bCsu2kdANRSmss6xHSzZg99ZYNojrQBGIRTGhKOsbLDuOFRgQWPYQia08@qks6yOxsXb9OrZzHwkN64PYUVwSE71zogBiAySyWerosuyDpTqQW4sbylFLt5DANrHkelyyAWUs@/q5PYoCGnZiuVjDjfO@rq2x7BsxsbaGJTdpx/XY1O8gsUaBZUdAwBpk2S4g3RGcyFm2CSiuRJZtAdaausDrA9Z3u7BDuCw7jQcIh4hlJ1TabR2x4FMt@NjMjRs33MOo7XVjmI7ivAWmQYk/GW9db77@erPbbY6ma1uv72DJzZs33PvT8ajZbS6qNRsAAdSBkqP@9FkAG99oNNzelSXfgZLBMyWNacND2xruA7BpAV1spN@4CSU3oeSqH1BibQB9EG0irPchX3ebtOQcaAnNJ80ma@IajaZDD69a8JU5GsBWYF7m9N3WKDARAyecJPgkn55W1Xr6xKQlpE9IUpgp5hxFOklMXdwhweOZTasTW6mD662aeAuUTPTLrFrU2VLCLScniOfZEjjfOVYohf6JF3R4wktqGfa9fIEtpSBny2wW0ElS4RVCIBGqhXqZLaAStlyWWLAFSBBxoSJbKKLCYgEcAXMO4xHBXtscR16jkUwee@6RIMR98gfU0r29PWFG@0x82sfI7CQn6YkdW0N8wTwB45/V1PbgczduRcEo1teFETgpKyXaSWjeYKF1IsuChRsSbiGQH9Br7AwpSccjP/KSqpEXMgR2mkbQaXT8npchB4u7brK89Wb2DuELgZs5uLtBd@T2CXV/wxKzi44i7uwuCVtgG2wXbq8HuzWcQJANn0/aELiNRYZxFp7TrjeJMjegZjtoSdLe02BZnAWS8GF38dMCnxSyTo5pO51R0H9jEHldb0Qa9jooVcwB/nnEQ3Jlwk0Yp@1GLpyg1mfjUglk52bXrmLlU0wsid1z9tg6udyqZVVP6@Awwhh3yAmJ7BMxMqeca8Me3gSnNmdOgFALOfOyUUnBpIW2rogFI9XzwEM4JMnwMDhORsHWAMxWSiX42iaxB26aclzBdlxBMJMJwQ69B7EretrDy8dEw1Zip3QlHPerSiKvpmdSQ5r33DBaUQtaqTpeqUpqPZFQTrsW@12HrWM/0F2FcPl6FD4tJvDO5zz@GF18Ti54QxO8hZ4HLpNa1MyFCDNcLLwkS5I1WETUKHjl@ILG8wJvglQC2HT9CjO63Hh4CfhrsPThcwZrv6hB@ciLxuBFwUv5nAWx751XGW7OtP1wSHJFhpsx89nccs6dlO@Q6dQVpXPyGiFdEU5hMv05B38ISlBMyjirZM1e6@6smQvRtQ16VpIZUitThiQnXvVHI9Fy9uO8hj8VQjNMPDj0F1XZEh16t8CwLMux5zf@SUOHAxZeYzziWjBtIdmYdcaDVuQHg9JtHC63FPtd1brw6I7fmxlZyaH@O6ym@ZwTLRl/hsw4Mh2sVoX@Ss9wg2CB4v1vBC8PvN@6zuJpziPDu8X9wr6xf/te5V7lOllVSkbJiEeiFh@w0iqv8jCyq@BY@DtbDDc8DXT10eCmyZWGfDbHZ59yD2s2t@gProNkFX8igVivwjmtLgBm22pZLZT8cPELRrIUjofeSCirea2kKarAhU7oTolW4GCQEFPzBa7OxUpzBQFwevmuqZwjL9hqAetJMQVLWOdCWBTG7YNTOHmD1@20u11fo5gsLyxdmVtzeJx5FQ6nc3pGndMHExmSeSxAH6xwTtDsAp6Su5C5KK8/kqz4sWiyUYmNZvMwC9wBvNRhuN/Yb3AMV@QdUeYJeNMxTBanPvQNUwMavDCFYf@CkQrDMLWkgExBn4nuqAS8SVmuCW9q4EcWi3kjzzH/Aw).

Comment: I haven't checked all extensions, but I think you can get rid of `toInteger` by instead changing to `data B=B{u::Int}`. The `x` got fixed to `Integer` by the code involving that.

Comment: @stasoid, feels like the last page is full of your answers. Great Job!

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thank you, that worked.

Comment: GHC actually supports the syntax `toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a`, if that helps you with Prelude. Also you can use `subtract 01b206` instead of `f 01b204`.

Comment: I just realized that aside from the one two week period which officially ended the challenge, you've kept within the challenge's two week limit with each subsequent answer. Really impressive!

Answer (score 5):

## 207. Haskell with ApplicativeDo, 9990 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLfFjF8kiWVKxil1VlEip9eHMeDHr4/GDPZ4djD1rnzPjXew8GNjBYh9seBYLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zzq4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRmRt2oodvfXvw7ihx2a@qijmw5zVNthLUu7Vq0EWx@xF4pmZ9OZQAChqlZn0FMNxy4GgkxmTDOaWgv8zDGvVEO7VS0ITzPWt8yOpfSY01UcptpNpa/azBw4/YHDzPb8ZBnGtnrmpRbHlD3N6ACYo1p9S3UofoWxU0NXeo2WMhWTncqwb0G8zTZV/Uvvi8OaZq@nGC0bIHOMvTEtW0X4pmrbJiZfZWy4pTankOYBVLE0c6@6/3IqqsDYSyii0tfVIVMatmMpTUczDaRJih3vnx4fTqWQZfbuZHt7OjTNXsdNg20PmlfTURl2atmKrkzjX2HVgWPuOtPhWVbtqIbC0olCIj0dmWPrljKTZJVZqtJqa7qagAZhcdZV9b5qMQxhbdNiu1AkPZ/Kp@rVccpEE9Pmx5HTaAtMz2ScqfqkU0B40@qqBpQwNR0pe5FTEWkvoqVRBoo1YmG7a1rARxYb2GqL3ZhWC5jL0EeRGKRnw1vWUGw1t4IIMh6CK8O8MYCJHBOatjFyVGaYRpwSI@AKk/fq04yVzmJo9WB3OjzH0nvTYavAaM2r9mxbpvPsyOyPpkML7I22N4@dMyneETbMFrTGVJzMDhUIomwmCZ9JT/aCJrQudGZ2aUPBWiqzDa3fVx0eCbyiWhQNqZmuGVe8gx9aZmvQxM7ndFXIGzss8oMdaEKqCusLMZFABwsSB3EwKMGx2VP95bWZoUID2X21qbW1Jmcsdeiohg1FthNMg0rcaLrOWqoOCcbYmzFmm9i846CGrnQTzUQAGRNzYb0rnWms2e8zHgW1gCJtp/JMReqxW4jXuzYb9nvM1noQ7TTNdltV2a3a70LyQMsMMPg0@1PV8nxLKsAYqksatQ8CAUljIqWBTi6FbiwFSGvZggaO1gPCak7IZqpiayhQIYmtGi2iat8TtSZTJlieXWvQ4aHqA4tw26pFXY7wQve0VECpeM0cvrE0x6Few6rsUFUsdmKpamRS7E5kCZmZmIODFUlQo66thbYOtkPQuDxFQulDY1qZk7evAgpLlNlSvQTfsiSVAlv7m@xu6QLdXMoCA/StsBJh5R@Ynby4UOE7lBvJjnUfAKwBoIrOkmbfSSrxPhQw7kABkwo60RW/Tif6ui9jtjbVFj6W41AtaA0QPuxdjGrWHFgWjiRjoipXUGndNDpAT6isNTCQHgbLpaAJmiYMBDGmXgPVQPJSG4FcQAqfdDVoNBubxNex@HhIBIUREdhYUNTN1zb1AcFBSttBXgaqQFLEuNtm71hb0XRMAvGIipfaUu2B7mCagdHClofxTm0lmFsM6rAW8PE1ZKcAUgoA1u/5@iUVCoChIUyqKkb9@E//rNXpAJ5qswmyTbDrO9YymzRyK1RYGA4ZMiwIVJ2KBXAxzJ0nhwyuFV1rkYBQjJHIggpBud6YA73FTMjQutGgl3aVa@jZ0LmajsqZnA/2MdZTrrg00TjnQsV7SgMaljKgvKnacfZiA1qpqQaCxDPx3sBp51m8v8VCdvL78PNi@PnihQqFiyQiy0vJZKcEDJdYpiDwhR7jnHfVCUlpO4ptaq1Af@R0TSPN4k0mNctmXzXCoQkcoVjIaoQiCZRy4UhJKzcTbc1ohUNrwIsVyDgUKTXLzXOtWCtNJfdnCWhuEA12VzXcjEgBEDnUKa6TPZDmCRgc3sWFyxdn2nUkOUYnfMFImOmwax4QJGUH@dJEBgE5lLB1Ve2HUwk5gmIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwUatFQ8FQ1F91wgA1nagodtYTzUSxpfe7OGgBUQy7DyOBhbzbhJEaJaOtOaBxxliD@JpGEZAsJBNv1JCl4pDu8RF1Sd7lMH0cBaXAMO5Ckz1Zbfk6MggB6MuOPSONdfMGMqQy4TADosPATJUONA0k5hWp8orwnChkskpc0QBsDZXl4w0NOgF2N5Dpgud9dQPwTJrDADbeSXyyp6eMAEuTD6vjDsO0NvSlHogH0IaaKsocED4qH1AwkwH1Pxt0bNS2U/F0NjvZx2a6mGMlq/GPIKRvk4/2JKy8vzOhoGFt9YbpitEZKB2Va2JMaTbVviMEFdTEdkAUTY83FBgXg2fC7gaWXkznTYOIq1qM80Ahz1tPDIUKSheh6MdBnVGZIkwV0BwtEEv6aDp3ALieylz6hCATBfgkPVAEVwMAJlOHanPggFQDBr7pas0u8CyWzuBykQ9C09lDkD93kOzxtpc1FkauPEsHEkkvCIvxIIo4tugsHhhcEVVlIoAa3x/wOGbF7s1BbHpFhIHAF5pIKgngva/g7JmGOQcpENJDiyCTMbwdQBM7RoUSBi5X7aLO6mmZXhNBm6Eh0EL@6zpO3y7COKE53UEjAZySPLFGu86BgcySdKyR5pjc3dDNBohlG/pn0s0h2Rw0tOFUhSjMa8NLO3ANCljbZmUYuT8PgOvCobYNApPCNxDYFyWR4CYU/FcCQAJKAKHCbZtE8TYIleOR0QxLCepKCeh0UoxJ2HElMHckTOXRZcPsoRRiZ6QYoKYHZp9moK0gZD6JfGXuUOfJftLrQqHEpakZ4bvQ4uJiqBiqgGRfXHwOrjV0PUdXFFzPyRUnF8Il0EUpYuTC2HNKgWG10P25i3kYqWGzDXFUutX6YeW8WMzUYsq5LJ5pfEZA1IFkA@g4PgBPKFIuozMSkSo3UNFEoz1Z@w2UzsdNS@sLIrxSrhXuF1TIEBm0Xh/NSEst4SD7OE16ZQtGQVBam92wFbo4T13ULu4uWtGL@1AMU0dKSrkBlYL8wr1ExzIHMFxGzleKcbkWiZxnYJBslEOp0HI4nI/rkJESiXyXj0QVTu1wSAWpHb64CAFRBX3Om12L8A1j6UjEIxWUAwdm0AnDocRdHvJvRGqRaAjSRkIxMDHKoRBQpolEsKnSyJkTBDo4es0JsxGNBogNTesKvzNiH8ISYGDx5NvAvxvHk2Zv7wqkK2vaOqoicYtrI@BNLvPAFj08javIdkljNWC4hRrAaNvyLCO0xo0B6c@k3Jr@jMgcRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOI29oQDATo9yNXEcLxG3WhDTA4TV1NnJFqIjHoOGj2qom52tAhH1YSTXvMA6D3gLOvK03o2JPoLiR2AQiBz5PJ@TGR0gziaVWJrJqv1REGlqZiIP1aGmntA83uInlBs0JTwmoDVVFlB91AJartsiaM@R2gtDrUHK7DAx8dY5IdxQ5HUGuscq0LlT3UGLBQ7hwADedmE@wdFTQHjOXGI9syrjXLNJDIiS1ADQxfwjaYQj6PvMBG1epuevNh@s5DDhSbCZZ9tPVjnSZu026ypGHqZsdkywCArJlIcMbeNXCqBHQ@B8xLZmu3RKBqxzRGUzyo4nBvo44o5zKe9q0gZJLgE5cga9j8So8BHqjz8e7HLRgh5GwqBeV3fSn6eJX0YZmuIwY22RhATNnqyDfYkh/Vfnc0MaGE/MGtSOAnU@Udk9v1CgyoUCrRw28pqb@T8xDo525Uy3XNq/sWaUg4leG3MiZqD8og9FNRHd5toIbBqWAMdUkxgXSmwcfti4LrIjkhtzzDKd7umY6SfJfo2gx/AqgvxDUm2cnQYigZj@OvRFEsXWHJlnqdRCklMINUPukO1IDa7JpMugDdxQ8kgQjtghIeh0qoFql5XjIxOR1wzAHoiy1V13qas0sTabqBStF4wHdjcT5wjOBQU52AsGTGghsnu8ZS3Ohw@K0hDnV2QKUn2z/Y3KofVk92ylJyYFtJXWtA32ip9R6otLpqS2z6E2RHKiAT6W@v9CPTdMqcEa509tVPENO4yfc263u760fVow@8EITG1noDXcGiFJemADD5MUW7/dU3w9i2zJ6n69uiIZYySHp1YjUBDV8Ru4KxA7GW4AvPYXgP1wcSzUCn2WRxk3u9QAG4ioC4ZkCjYycaRUhaQ/ACBWSeUOI6QsJquIEFDPRWECbm1sfo5sU/nEhgvpNT94jcNgZ231ezO1mm8Gun3UZ9wAtOU/BVHDuRPg7OUDBfgZic@xdkmYmaC@zhWyF8fOViLr6ZqLnAHr4sx4crHvPRTcXMA/WQ5QgZrpDMxTUVMQfQw7RKmPyrKuO4PMU9tKQi8pob/WAiD3eBcOOyyxgVLcKIIBcwzbmjx5dE7DrOvo55JC1PxGIUX0hh8RaYPWsIgvzyBZdYIAj0Q7vfSjhDZ4wi40cRB22GL7B48ZwRZL2u1KFXjkvrhviiWFwHASbnxomzXmJzKqmpjYM9cN6uab0OImDg69JuiD/KS8Sb0F3J8XeKNG9By@yPfH35Ls2J39OEOPH1rgwnN8kh1LusiUhO7b67mjMRx7slX8GpX/JpwLpYwMF24YLwBAb1PRNUsT3NpnVVv2QMeCbDRUBy7Z4JBV8ax6TH848sfj1/4lTyIyKZDWL1ykRze@yqpxJyFrF4KHpX@mzKNmit9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvQabfqZA1AUc3IwLOIiE1LlFa4r4LShCTaEekNgNLtAyIBamqEkj@iB8wzzyjM5YzJRmIbaHoB6nQTzD91fAYsX8gTZbjS0h0CBLlh09zm3kkcDMHHSiZWE7NpTOEMJNhWf7jjZPSBA6L/dmWk2NtEUzsByIJV4/qeftaBJZhusq4zIyPAcdaAkcUv7wfYTSdFDP/PbmmAuB7qmEGHI9TWUTQVXNhTdc8xHjToNi8e7itVDXV40N7Ar/kB/e4TzeMktVR@0VPc5PxMi8eRkHk9taD2qETzRGCXT@4HkU1ORPD2Zc7qptAgLN7o0lRJZ2Pq8XdQhNz982i1IpyeU050xZOMlOqc7cAb8F1flvtauWh@/86lSnGSyVFZpyGrStJWGpj7CB5ZyNWiZ8f5VhyqNRcvNgR3Xv4ETXPG2rlxxZx2d8wnAq2hpnY5quc@HwG66YEeQAZS8occjrOLqWoy0Z@UxnJbOfx8CcffFeI6H6aTp9PMtDEks0oReg6TFpfe4j0zaFGF1pTFCQ7D77ZyFGZISC4Kn3IxGUxkcdb11lvEif7//cHocqil9oTA/NV/05ySZZ8Qk@WJ/nE@CUZ3F8v9Xej2MZVpP0ePpls/5oFh3J1jHrjmgNCsQb@qKDczkiOZQr6H56OcxBsfhqYlsNXY9wt7j4rjLbQ@t3IheKnpy09Q1G7uz/pAYnZ7sHueJ2y7oZ5wUfbOEbZFebHfjnmu@JDCbDi6bPMBoT5BsfMUC14R8nJMwHyJa07zB74PaRte8Vvnv/NHudm6pniCj4jqxhNacK0Bbza9xKi690898Ol7NLZfT1OeGiwWCSdvgqbxsa7ppg5GOv4@RAtRt2@a/87nYTzVNMeI0j@13z08mCtVnCTFv90BbKnrH1HP5TlKBnwcbfGC1UfKL51MlniexZPnrEstVjExDFs8HRf1V0rr6GifQZLeFi2I@5yPj7DyxJRZTHq4gGBS40j2/ctupPKVMJPmMyUMNYDW7N8rIff6E0eQh6rqjSX9EijbofZigkAeHY3Hl@6fktvJ4bq2niaQZtKtfq4Svca90FQYv@p1pUpZOyd@YQk6lni6g2vpAHahz5dNB41LFvY6PmB9PL1RKVGNJzC0mgXg4s@hB3Qoz8kmlxnEbfY8KGEXXoJN/VbuZK@/6oIv30fI@BMchOmYTdoxBf6JxJ8w34@hxynX7bs82WxOFxJhvlUj5r@tQE@q6rdL3IdV@q2eCsWz2QG0wntD@AilNg/DfCcQUMlY0JmZL5mbvrZyDLguqB7SodmXHcaL8aUIn/ZCFT8CFAlhshuqM8PchSs8Tog3T1L@lZUCWtjTa06zHcRfr11poRs0RmyjYeC7DxnmRRvuhWQw@zgjjEqiHhrTziOnsn5t6xBqcmWd/ZLTyzbp/zb6EkZqmiWyr6bofYkiaDZET@cTqo@zItVCzoeoKfwxzK4/hKyQyj@LztA6h3tIqDa7s8LWc8TJbcEr09EdALK0FtklX7ankfUSpV1qXA9t9PAg0NPE7JzqRpJWJB9L1NejrBv5OrBv5tCHHNMCachSro6I5ouNSqQh9SL66Cx5zibvbUzoqP/LwmOgYz0rg7jpuxI2d8@cninzDSxOS8f0Aj7MCdJwrdWS7z7kI34ya0J6D3ten2ab6eBOnQ7/aqRPJues8X1H3jK7ZNbpq16LO4fke6h7AkQ4/rPJYJaD8XcW@wu2EJI/G1lzX9lNXN3X9KdRFecilo2nOn6ndwqMALUj6TXhHSgMixOOrU3gwZBORaOx@qO901QGMTLbpmH01Tr6HQHWc7OG/8yefdw9CNjvTVKvF90LgzJ/iaA1dZTcaFOHS9i9Ez59IauimgjtWH1HegTLu8ylTU03T@uq8R0cxnX6fHvW@PrDph6Z44@35c5dFtk0lfQozaA7fhsJZVu2YjWZX@1qRGqriGNpV0p3D4d5H7VIhjKnmGotvYnBC14BW1iiBTFD2xx/jY/eh8c@3pjO39hsDyxp9XTBMbgHwplr5kgE6HspfrNbOiaYhH/dZufuJHlm3EIu7D3ITKdCoLMfVFGgl8oMzQBNbyoT0olXGB5SeqXpTYXwLa98ydSl2B9Aknubb4QDh8yYvHhKEO0K@gVUY3hl07MjXGbfbAp0Kf@YirHbw9BZfWrJ188Y30QxdXzHEY@6o7C1DPrYmkn10USSRFIufcXXw4OyWrvVt/svi7fRcLLOr@bNQo/mWrmieltrmyxTo@ppm1zMt3FcPKkS8aal2E2e8UfpyqchFjmF2QArHdTYGdmHnVmF2A8E83WRyhIu/31c7Cu6z29Nwy51uzw56gHl6L8FTEL8dKLb2dmA66lyc03sKnoLyjdLRmjsTreAidKkrNmXxx0QnwKDZhrjpajZtb3Yd8zsOZzNanp@NnJ5U947ZPT4R4tOLxC5TFt9l7m5Uz4HT@hivzM1rUusUK/MPCjrNoQlT8Zxbz/n7Lx6bRbgZ9PoDWzzm597Dwwr@mePeFYXbNxpIwfhnELqsq@jO/Nll3@Qp6FNiJBw7H9KyP2q62WEf8ykG6hcIOFS6H2CsdRiXDxUHeoAxh1kp/yeuW@LcRJwrNfZnYAQ1w@KaoTmPz8M4jgJ2kPvECnFVCw/jJPfwN/HiWzHET@ZTZe9RiQ9D@qipg2XzNajDD1@BUDe@PrR8ZdkFhkrTGDhxPMD42BCRe3SIKLJhPufjARZ@u/XmNOKyQqfb5Jsbv6KJ2SpYdANbH41dD67@z@EwDQ9uPyxkZ1O4psGm2lYGunOEK3pPSVft93Wc2QCZvmnOJODbZo7oRKh3dsiOiS2vEKZZ4uCinXBPBwdpezCdJHJPlrAgnm8aoErimFaCEVw4rESjkUiAJ8JlnY4BYC4Unc/Es1v86KfNoOUdgtXa7PycLd0Ni6mifM/KTCpKrFbjWPFDJ4m2hn06XHnEk58vKbXyUigeDy2FLowiS4U8cFUH4TYXXJmAbWv04OUdk4AZCt8Ejm63xiV@Ns3u0rlPUORbYBCcGjRPh8YFP2HFj@@d4EaSv/nLljgO21Ghsj0NFAwgCJ4GN3tq17x5zvMVuUOzKXicFnHAWKTzw13xjSoDIQmWAz8Fa96w0@2TvDhbJ46eg@eQa5ZeKXjj4twV7ox3eOPx0ni7nEXGXiq3UtAlBz0DbLWW07UT7FijTe8Da7zHFFwIZjgWGqytGNtlLRWX6@ksA83R6KZ5RYeSsCR/85f8RCGdaBA7zd3s6SSxL0c8uCDTMb5m0xxAqV0kt6plCpAwEhlGpgHOfjIUVhQewX3@dNQRODLuHvSjbPhpv43qMYtvsRCeqsfzQyWtHV6qHr18d56qlX9gvaT6n36WjNwJwknfxQs5W4oxF6R0j4zlj85C9Dg2xKSlocQz9I57aOK4xw1vDyCRwpkMT3y4PGaafdFr6LA2nU32uFFcGhJGN7Wze@KvR@e8iWHVGzrxR5uhDRyx8QC1YUMHA2@EUPNeV14KD/gkXfzYYVnIEE9NKuDiJ8PpAASeXsMkS0P2hXWRyeJN3JQPPk5IHQ9M9srr7o6ujH/fXXJTbQxoa8l1OpHOlKk6S/XyWoVcltoy8eDy@fcXw3QqfjFc3aolbZeoFxfD71Lp90B104JUz5LY87b2N@@WEpXUly@2MmKSdB8q8X2CICaW7g53D7eOT6onp8fQCveu@Nk2rZ4yljXIRbTNvmvqdCQc6GJpqv0N8sfzAXg4zJYUtoaXnUQiAf8@bwIVtJbi0hJ3@kTTROqvJJ@X3lZ98bMAQqa1NeZy1C4Mv9iGwGxINaz8oI8H25lIKw7nEpdpKOOxA3mEwd2Yc2QpkUpiZSBWHIj1RFKxhyv7nIc9hWJfxfI42Z7PBUGKefmde/G8inNJcP9bqXcfBsrfvN4cy@P1JphH6g2gXqibZru6u3d6tDWZDHiMniR1y4WsOODAhTP2ND6/555GplNmIiFOcJYlJlEC7hWDGd1k01CdGxWqJYRjs8cTE4dS@aXAmDGBMmW8DqhW4rQIh6kEqIOUsFpT5y/a2tBXRHeM9qG741X0hMC25KF2C56QBOYgXc2SwI9bDcQqyOV2vUMS4kJeh2y/@hNzexxWDcdosJ0o1QNDlTfq2Az@faOS60rX2JCJ4UyusThLw1dXjQ5U2IWNlPgYxZY4IaQlXnbJKy9eCwJlal0qNM9AO//EERMYpXWlj3cQCOh9sO2L7PPApJNyrjDx9IsbtGIVfgMONW1TwdrQCTzDwfsE3HGL8O1uH5dRO@OqGcl3P88NDByoAMh3Hw2oyBZeHdQmWc9vtuAkN8UlCu5QSRPPtjg07WkJNrvWbJqYxkZoo46jg6TE2oiK42VQdEaSVXUbdJIWDN/86iRSThK0X51vWo8bTAoCTyY8lTHGpADC2uXZQ/UwlN40YVj9xBMvERxhtn04Q2uL8ThQrqMZ7uVFRZw/p4nFInOsAe7yqIRmkrhFKJIr3nV6ug9wzvUiF2ryx3/6Z/xKkQsH3D8X7mFqHXx/KHxtcP8TN0aWwffPPF8afH/Efd8nsclm71EQ2Quz6sHN/cCXL6SZOqFMcG9worp4rY0t/W73kNk0yY9t2VOGvmZCCYM8pxlAL60HTHFNbYzgPIdxE47xhM/fAYsAXwF/oHqDGg3lp1q1MJ6mLyaTWHCciUjQjnB1yGf46XD95wFeKgNKWDKXza3ISShk/NpFSCdcO7gFmSOMRIogEwPXWr/8qdHEoyZMspuKrpZzJc4bySXl@4z0ySvoEsAGuKFwziANnk7xUkBcRSQLLylROYJJcSALySGUaS2Tsxpog2FyAEgEgw33IB@om6YgFfCxoQ4d0phGrgHUwMvDcGZS5VcLuYjigIjjxqtPprvjeFMxnsrwddCEvxmkMwQ7RrCiNI9Zz79nF86FURNX4DBgvF/OYV0D3P94zr04nLPwzO/shSzh6etUsDbsxbFh4ubzbSgtC6eT6UxSzkV8HCoJVFBe7OpfACV0bhAWTVW7NPt2dWNr99XB4fHMxSIEGZoGC7FQZS16EU/EzmueI@SVe5Ko69vJ4zfr2y4p/aUa789AiPEmjelizsttuqQP5H7Gd3PP5k0RMxnJqaciphXR@DbtYZrFPo5N@gA3@GbSmVzDkbv789pa5cIIzmT/Zd5lS8HEMjIXuC5sumopNF1MLOKuu0f9BC9xtBPu6aW0NL5KzDtzxf3j4IevBvGuhBzfD@Luhg/Q@drxGdzEA/vkoe6JJM@KLsfgBXPLC7LGLaqMRR1n2AzM7LHxl4aJuszeXikOkHlEOuBzSO7dgzaHtEk481kmuqTHo5kHd@JixK4/vrFDXFXRhdLpWiNwI05Vu8fvvBPVCbuva044EjAExPRBvFlI@9GLLzwwpXw@ZN6JMht1xmGCZmjDdK/UTS3A7w1h7vUeUboh5HAAdDs0@2w8i7apuq4j0KnY5oDP2Kns1aAHcG16HKk4WqigZcUhMdAz5BblHO/EEJRI9FrZ8DCS6KrDltaBEScciYFo@k6Wx3eLKHg5BuhVjXk1wGmpfleBOmDTZNbwao5hZK1A3nEF@Twuu5kfbNQCgAyTNiJFPnMROjXca6Cw4YssFPMo04jEQgnGLSlxwxPtE6CJqATb6OKuSpr6aLc1Utn8J/b5YN7WrF4CawXDDGehl7in2s8133TNi48yyrmS0IyWOgzjifpiDekE4aGbs@tQRJphcbprRtws0pq@dMaVhYojhNL4wpYpeVcoeHJuUjQUCngqH88mglECOR471h44QUUIt3tKn4UHdGuPzRKMvOGLsBGzHSvC4hUcrm@YwaJRmtOAB0WAzYKgbXJpdD1CGC@5CyfL0EgYahstfNxqfXYuJxI1cFMmEbaE85kboE3hTGAkADYqJCkSWtAv4K@IJeJXkibE1aRLlG2ALs4AqLnRJKdwMh7kC9CCas0qz3wXDowFDKdqoVAUrTEp7QsM@GJtjkAEtHOkuGsjAH3FWTKgGspogNqw1JYG8vLFa9UwVCAQ8EwPb2BVBsBkViTmXg4cG1/eRzkEeRF3xOE0KOjkpX5boTvdBHVtKVmiqbHSPag1ny5Qr2kLzWaU/G@TiWTpLrykl0dJ0DUjlfBStyxHM8vR6JKxHF4yUNt69gxn1O6XQJmrJ8BAHQJQfEmPlICfQfkrLxmlJWUtvNQqp5cpBXjBRL6DBD/YycTdknKfXHoGylIMQiwudMJLNt23k0ok5HsoH/aQpWQMeOYOL46hK38x@yUtGsUyJJbqWIAfkhfHURo2L46TNHlXErZAstMT3W1KFfNaYuaqYk5AEVz0BqwsDlhio2HdBR5f6ZeZF/eA@sczfo3bsRntIlFtv/ElTcY8XbAIOY0yVwiZML/wCAg4DAMR0RtTIhEQJr/@dVDOMSY9z2XCZvR5NlWKhrIymOlgXwdfgB6eXJYs6e5iM37N1HY69zl@rrQTn2uHV4eH7yMXYVZgoeDGgSSvSN/jrcxP@6yy9AMf9tM/weByMhBMLsvPVpPJT58@gcUBn/NKogLig38i5/FQ7Ty8ylhldXU5lssvx16E6r5iRcLpdOSYaVqSXWh9u9WCr9ml@7nDQf55/pzyAvMf/hkPE/kLh@tBEBEa/Ea4ayUbZBerirIcXUm/MEqJdCr9N/9u8T52d1hf@5vf6yXVRXwc4OPn92/QfSxnv1tc/G59fWUlBoTk7sOPhx@q1erKZix7eJ59vhJPLa79x/9jcTGdXksnF2u2LddC51fvpXRqRUr8zV@EDg/f1m0bCFHAT4bJ4MTfPHxlls2yK3YLn6s2w39y37Z8bgXdjfYtXnIE9kqZhE0olM2Ejr8PzW@2RSZXnq/@5z8@@Bx0gpV08syCpxP8HMzlg9wJDvBlXN91sBJcQ7DcfXCULJfL4Fz9z/8rpK@8AjwYM1qDn0rWxZUbBSvxMiX5EqzkwCGn05Dv//WznwWClWHwNijLcnBEf3V0wyf/TH7G0JGUVvOSab7AG8TxM/R9xrVIynL6wm1PX3Nj03rBXcAN7cpMX5jX7h5XMcEN5HgqXAV@tvDzt//73/7p3/4x/f0pff8DXkydW3zxaZMxFUZg/BSLL2baYW/Kf5SIwyfh9Y4geuOiZsF8OVbnpfJYOOhzTNHB@2WCJJ7/G@ECQfd2VZRDtYnGuAjK@ZWDF8Mnf9i40C5tg2OSepmz6TC3MTwPc2UB@xa4QPCHcvnIwb83Dfw7tPGPDX/KB9nhOXwW4Y/@4eN58XeRQkQwgcx@Fn8D6RsIngfPa7UdA/8@d@nPwr/GZ/zbu8W/zw7@nTTx7@gz/p3c4h@bqU0guLa2FoxGj0BlFEz7lM8pfBOJuvB5zBsMBH@rH7ZykDt4EYA@UYvG7@/PE98Po6WS@AdlquT58MNdUKzafTy@9n0lGj2n4p1XRDnX4rUKlJUXmX6@XwPE0bXztbVEvVKpxGvfV87XJhOJdC9eRLGjvoCEldr5eSB4h21Rxp9l/Gna@JuWpCR5UazDOF0AFyMnPUQAozcroD8Q/LT2KRx9Hn2e0lPXKflKvnpjHoz/Dw6GEKENU5emleqmunILJCVLqaepUWo0TPXMA7kFThX@Uj1waqn2MNVJGSlDlkfDCVQP//cOTOfNgQnYTEjpDFMOIk614dk5OHgD@NqQ9yX8aalUagiFHKau4T@lo9ymS9vo@X09chE4Z9InFbSChBxKpEKJXCik1bK5/mcpFqpfnIdqpWDSvrhIcn2JpVdKdFnf/X29vrW/Wa8nkYPWlqIvovEX8ClXomvi8TxYKT2/KMax5TjnJerB5Nrzi0omju5cFJonDWFryeg3fsYo4VlZvAiACXh2ht@zm@sb7iIHuS7OzrxY/EliELkoCD4AmpybfsLBQPf8Hf23Dv7L@n9zysLntQhj4bv7tTB9IvgXidzd392L30okHBae8Br8YQD4McndfQWdBHQHrvNwpBa5v@dh8BuOrHGEFcxjrUKJx4DQVYM814tQiTGwlcJime3iYphKRUoNCPEm3JUvtGITKdFelqUGrrKBfSAvRwgku1IqrQj3ar5Uygu3nMuVSsseVAo8wglAqq00S8jopWA/gmXg7B9O4TQL3YgaCrfUNl6N/7zfB1tPLqS@fPGC6vWWZtXrGJ758uUCelIIt7KUC1kISeW/fIHuF4qAHbhvikXUAlh1cjI9Rt9VbMVxrDBY@rGLEO5Psy9CEYxPp1IIjOlZdm0tt1Kp5FbAnctHIiVpie@DCXeiBTlyv5SUeDXAQgsFRZScX41Q6H0I41lwjT2vAIfb@GF390GiNlvJRsKNkRrxAuRCgYewlVw4Hy2Iv/JihK0lK8tM/J2fZ6Iry6vLL2q18ciFYqJ0p5Tl@/KdUsRpg/tSU9xHittBlWfPMgWgSz5VugjU65vVk2odX@yAS9IgfRkGksAJ4HJj3wqd0xxPtlA7x5rULkKhYukFb9h8lgVDJQEXD4HoYvkCVTgIhqTWxn3gQ8LKv0V5OZ1ZTGaH3@W2UqB4f1nGz/n5eT6djy6DaFsuFGq1GoV@WaQ0571hu0b3UpXj53IuW4uj6nI5bC8H@0xezQSXA33aXLSaYi1cn7VwzmwRAqFdWQOX0m1V190rYG9MS2/daC0VsB/uVTe2TmLpNUCZ3q5uxNLHp@tBGb3ZsZ@iM@g/2qpuHpxCgsO9rerx1svdd1unhxBuw/gIxIJP71BRB2pdvRkMbtBfV@mzodnK5aXS79f78Bm2f/zlH/z4y//uxz//ox///A9@/PM//dUv/vQP4PuX8P0j/vyjf1vI4u@vfvHP/ucf//WfQ@B/gO@/h@@/@9Uv/sXP@Jf8fw3f/9MX9tfi64PjXyAlYPvDX/3ij//iV7/4J/8Svv9KfP/l9PfHP/nf@P9/FH/o/PMf/@Sv8Ud4/uCPfvz9P/7x93/vx9//@Y@//w8B@d//1S/x/4//6u///S/x/3/5N3//V//D3//h/0SOP@OO//tf/Vv@@3e/9wd/9/v//O9@7xcP/P7Bo7@/eEL4L34HIU8v51PwPKVe3xryi59Unt@EGuNciMH@9B//@C/@EXDun3Dffw8@@Peifu55vJgoGXXx6Djw54x9SYLelHrxxQMFlP8jhkIw@zKJjUJTbuivfvHP/wKDJ2D/kR9DSp6FXUJgL7efA@y/9grmh/35j7/82Y9/8Q9//OWf/fjLP0SBFl8pxKqxuPyVeSEAzD4BDgFzT4EDQHkNl8gX2WIgDY7FNZzHCMjRT5@ApIvgAv17OZDNgA/tmOlPrVbBz8V5snKRvKjwTw38iWQFQxLJiyTGJ5Ko0csVQgaligYgZ7CHlvlERBTnH@A7DKwUwIdTE1EYgqI8KgpR61FWLpejgWEZ4ggUvJhmyCp5NLrQ5igDXkzE08TqedBq2XCdsEDKcvSI1ZfLQ54wigEVwsCwQBh0JMlpKZovb0KG5eEmQ1yIPBr4BM9P5Uq@PKwguh@oCIAjug5ZAlQZSzes/AD@MuEE@MBw8wcoSr4cjVbyEFKmqlJusTrlKWepclT3KKN6YzgYwPB4/oKx7yQ5L3HbD9qCCWj8jY6hn9MUyHOIv4gui@rQv@uk7zKmh4YeEn14GI9/jsGUXgAA3ngc92PBNx7H0ryA6CFHFaVs4RHlGIByUTGF5AXQMB0NRKl9o@SB/KEMT/usVXweRIfVWVpaAtdaRcpIB2BKMOuqaDuKhcsVpCQVmZQrSBiM21vUpUMyNpY3l@FXhv@tRdqiysmxHFgKoS4QYm4e8WjGXDGDVHq3alSXZSp5lOACwXE4V3BpzQk00xUWCYTpUvQI2apqvw/PN3Zn3RyCEhqTpJic47PKEWHKfjCLxfIP8spqAJ7kH@B97OJmcGgGfEdXAnsZErRyF6ceh07QV3KBSkWsmzE5UDneOoEEJwdMTqcSDDTXu5XV9Ep2JZvO5HLZ1bS8kius5LL5DIi4XCqbTsuFlZVCvrB6T0V6AaIiVlxuZNcq/2Dm89/8g3mf@aH4CVTes2GCxe8DlWE8nkxTictydrU0KkM5KChQIU2M6@ijuzhulwxc0PasO9wJBMUK3MWRTRfgwwILAbYAQfABtLhiwMQy9u5BSazn4Zsu@JqeJGeBESKBC2AEji3Qn/wEsNmegax5JnNnNjd2ptB5gues9iEHaASD7eHOScdkJybfobeuNgNr4oRQJRCg5Y9zIGktgBfJn9cCa0kvdj6mjS5//duGZYKG@9Nh1hXjikdtanitY9PxonYUvLzJ7mlO9wGI034PTxSp1u8Mw1avAQXEaU4OsA4/lm6a8wBW2enhA7V8453bxHVEOrgJ4Ee7L3dOfM@TrerGTiDH1g/2N6ceWQGUZXtb2yeed5XHukmzHooPW3t7017xQCtlkWVXYzGQjvCDzxh96JlY@t4FkRMPj7upGJhRdfWYv/7AtKG7ysDVSwUZ7MJ0djVVyBSyhdWmVV6PHtUHeen5opQBU7SpsA7EAuefGoNhO50H8VOicyVluRRMFXOp/UFvYDnaChhR73HnL4oh3FxWkPkhCc0O7ICZ08Or4vFWASdgqS0weW4MOv/RwBc@DfrswUB4YBA6La3ThfxvTBcg0FAUBt9v/UB61f9xHg9weB4UNhOjzwHH5TStzVKBBE2JpQv5bL6QSedj@UJ@JQvWYDYmp2Pyan61kIrJKTkv5/LZghzLrxQyKyAoIRYaIxAEgaK1k0kYB2RJoieQHq9zXcN7cc1EtxII8hkFGHzxTYZBxQsY5JmUyV@kIJ0UwI2zTCsvSviu0BS@iRMQKqzJgtvbG6ntbUlaRw9O/G2kJKmFnmw@lVpdlySVYjZAlqclyeRpIArAHO5JpdY3JGnAEeABVEnqomcrh1qrJGno2ahub2M@l@hJY3oAu@Ix3KO7nlUAM9CTyZDaK0mfPXQAV@UZrVBJt9CDeWLMNo/ZgDhJeumWJ5UCDEccjmPYcetarUrSLvdUqxjziiqe5UV9jZ4qfSTJAg/woCR1wNGxwD6XpAY4kRMlqQmu5kiBsB648Kyi4SiSNOIEQhJJ0pCgleaVBBqWCMdsdnZ2lK7TUjv8M7L4swlFgxhtONjabrx82eh0GtaouvXyCGNevdpRLkcDq9FpiGSNOnxMSAMxV73R9AfKuFuvK/rcmNcQY0zF1Ed1FctWVz5DmcSng5n06q8g5hXEzFtO4djg0wPQBn7We/BcVxoU434ohp7DRkMqIY86o76KEy/YZWgDUskf0lOalllCF6jkbDEUDsVG53ItdluiGNZjLBy5S5XuEaQdpteAoMQE/edudD4sp2qgiMslnBMKL/aeS3IhKxUXlefhIbpzUhFU8RUpUsRXqJjtEAvF5ecgBnOrUnEZntJzKQPOYTgVSjEGP5Hz1dpzaRWRSM@fxyUoC3gBRIGE0moBERZWQS0o3QM9HJC7jYGj1uvh8I2qXEUivE78tUvs7Owscsc3XWlUR6fUDg9jwzIvDdMipVso/DSmlgrD36DpmBbH1wEK3D5PFamSkH1egtxZMhlZQ4GEIgSen2hSO8GKcf7CETmfiyRwi3bdbNfp6n/2yZ35Pjubcc36QV88w5MWdMrS3ZJDqrJdDJygUknvM2R45ruBrwCiA8VgrfDLJ@iFPSqomIVAoCK0rBN16CR2VNwe0yyJsA1@ajHhOyULRPmo9fEC@RKdVMZh6Y1pKC0mgtkNZV@vVMr18u15LR7H4q6tkWkJubmJYAxj6wIYT0y4m8br5XUoWKpk4FULKnqXhsFhoNJSHAUstvW7QbEIsPelTvkcE3/Bn7W4VJEgq/MvNdBIodlGQaVsDxp0JJ@lGqAy50pDCJNXV0ptYGealR7CaHmXleMVOZ0vZdPxCkJlM/hcvS/pTCnzEyFLtC9MKfnLHo6UCGu5HdbDjrllQHVSxSLWSilXyAtPJRJNL@vhlsmUtfgt8Ct0Btx0Dz0kUgovRsq2@pnryV90nBldrJdTXGNesge989RiTo7dxevxe12xnSV5NV08Hyydx@Xa4mLqS2dN@gi1hmrfB0C59k/cwjBXgjCX//jAOB7axmH9EmgyugpEkgvpkgAJ9EUnCEssjK@j4puRwqHQajoUioRKALUIwdSXInfE@iHokKFn0A1haIV@WEhDvKU6A9DwQEDMlIBbBTk5ELwPtDS7z1YKgeBd4P7ufq3iKlCv2WikROOu9xljnSjYh0laaMIlqkVyxROVF6xarnaOqiUBWt0gKy4ZYBf8iFs8ufity1nRtcr3/HmBi5iQTYATh9Z6k2vRCs16BCRJCkruWkQ4nwXTDydYfgjSFZBs4649MOhaiOIbJJdS5PrgeS3yw76m3@WB3ci2AIa6vw9G15K4QJqoJIlYzQPaPxAIGqZw4sy0A10VZE02K6GdqbL@ceH71e/z3785PTg92GYvUsV8Mc8pccFNv5gckkNA2Reg5GhHW4Fg/4uZlX8wXpWCxX4osxLKTKiuF2VxwDuMfBA@x8Ub@NbOwYKsRcBVLsvP5dWiZou1lXDRHvRVK/JczqWL6ZQcCdoVPH2aXg0CkdAl51aDtSBHurIaATctC6TlYCUpguVVTBfnPmDhbNAGpsi/@fSFMfcFulqaXMmkKOnS/do9/Ffuz8Fsvifr@Z7@8ScJP/ccgP4xgeuhx/gzATeGGcfXfoiv8f81@tk44IWWctAKwU/Q1W37@/r39WAgWAhVoskQvgyef4bCIkU9ddmgP9Vexr/vxwHLtm0vez7wLkOdWbYiM9Bsk8mLyNs06LSFQi6fCwZ@PftJLoP9vLxQZSF@xRIfE/CCRe94U2jilVY45bG8EN88Pth4vXWCg4Jq4CtJ2cbBfgKj8K2Z4/NpTV1VLH0kXps5QigcS042DhlYM6ebh5TmjE4mUijNbIhclnZbRfFumdg1kxMZXC7LJlMrSTnL5HwxtVpM55gCcsjGmwiEawmTMqrWhtkfcUskvBGhxAtVhMG4PQ1sRVstspeHe5SCLilYXtjcenPADvb3PiTcUB5@srN7zI4Ptk/OqkdbUI83W8dMqh6z3WOJne2e7BycnrDq/gcG0UfV/ZPdrWNEkAygDEPNiBPMMwvYmj2yk6g22WQbTATbZvNKdSbDFauvJPHG0MlgA18oouKt@5PhAwMG1Zbf7DiuLnAdhCF6pdWyAngkUmuyBbQ5FpZVC/cNS92Uvcqyg/e3KSu7yJor@6FV1kztG5m1VaanxB/TV3qZI7a4uHhhSN4A4K@GZ/X4g3AzPYSNy7T7cWshnFthy2DrpFci45j9g8OFlOtbODs6WZC9uKPNhbTn2d1eyHieLfCteL7ts82FrOdbr75eyI2T7W8srHq@za2NhbznAyZdKIxx7m8uyKmAS6xrU2st0EvTwtu7e1tsGYAipYlYnG9Cx1QwECI8MGx@PwWZecvLN10zRkpzYzQF3VK/Bu2CT0AtoMJzjnStxdiy2YefntoDYEgW8LRYxeo0YwIr3q4Dw0rgLrCAFVrACgH8Ap6MRji2WGbpCIPohTZfuQ/z29ZiTDq16fzjdzZbQ320AswQo@t66BwspFDF2xMDC/cCZbhNc3Jt2txLoGAaMMmSIhE8PLd/urfHM4OBwTKtsESQjDzSHJxmH7BBFeEXqw6hvHF4s1BbIK0WhFaBb3gM3E@0ZmC6NZEUUM@FhSYgmKTutaLHGGpVMVwRRrzo4ZvyARiiwZ0CFz81GA43sa4d1WlSgSJIzK2DbV5DXFMus8lWjjDMlChF0Xy7/5cvzPVdOJNea9JrhDhugZwXi@PjJS0jbATDFtzjmgRBR9Mp5QJyTDQKqaE6FOer1wIQHb78JLtbygpklAqxZ8@oHGvgK4QoC0wXpRxZHEEQgSAYkQ@ReUVbpOJGFpLLuOWDvx4diYjjCL/AszHybuEAyTpd0KlW9Xqh15wLBlhhpSmBLKLaLWxrcGfSdfCjeAROjrEGdJMYcyPlHEaikRNjaoy1IXhKptY1AzhXtcYy0WUF6IzU@vubvIX4lTMUzgOoxiD3itRgICyeYfclRl9YaFhgi5ZcKJCHBAV8i0wTRkJwuMfTHW1SsmXeX5AtMfVTUu5uF10@4qmBHQSnEVnxlgDOK6K6FFgZA83gF8iw/5YBPWdJjiwaFRAelwmwrUm4eJzD3bt8@ZVKbE3XYvGba4Fi@cFabD2xGr9ZLWBYG7MI1AJEfBjwRgGafiZbMz0PBYyFhIJq89NQwAA65iXo4xMInpAehtxx@vi3p4dBujjdlaHfQgtyqcCTTHqbk97WpBe7L4QoDGyC9Ar7whroknPgwtPiLA@OFpeVkwnbk16aAykz1U3T9iQwzwF4DkUlB0MGnBXGKEESNr5sQOnhK2/KrLpd393fOpmMRXwJuy4K3sVXy1MekUkwUSCMt8PoiXglCreRCFzfDB/yPGJEz/rxydFW9U0Myhdha@MeMK0DwI/oCRM1uHdzgFBDbcJ43Iqx8HGVLUfYMyxZjInJAvQ8OQvdtFVA9WCOrUE/TVmlOIjnn@xJQeyRgTlZSWEWjrAvFxcwpKZWmdzrf8n0MsZqpsVGmVVUdjkeTwcRUt4VMPu8a3JlAyFb/Ga54tzMLlMptmJlmKN2QeMepqxZ/FSvexzbaFh0z7T2TTLK7BLDI8QoW8QNIDAuTqo2j2uRNDYiH2AodmMIw@Gcps2ipJ8je1Ksq2DxsrTUby3L1zTaybLEeVnWKNPZMvxazDWCuRSYOrdMF6mYfaev4NFeEXnQx8mUQwyyAgE@yeK7Tyts4mtGnEiR7kFBmVKv45WS9XrYVvU2vuJ8YDVhyEd12RZg@MHYBI@kjoSOyUhBHtSfJiNaGh7FxZs/YdSZQkhvWi/T7X1hyjEQ8EpmO2qfSuUrBs6T4Qt5/RmCgT3hh2bFI3K@EkeKQiveVrA/uMjOJ65A4jgGdjc2JxjE82yox6Zz4jy2mROHN93NS@Ie3Z4TdznozSsBCIYHYsThyzkxhnkwLwG/QWgcUTv3EfDcT@BaLRyZ3/TQryZb3HcFFNH/xBqo4j6j3QMfC4JyKTjQ19bBTRWYtqnh5e3TiLzj35AyPIz4TqJ7bBUZc5JiNzVtGr2LSSCio5R0PzkbFptdwPqdnM5HYj6EPox4RWFP0R/CyXxIoYRzkATZMfG@O/1pe6iRBafxjtMn8CIFowXm3TiB2X8EHmPHsNj4LvAC3oHlxXjMPKfLjdEVZxmHwnHSHZtfnrgt7CFotxJyxE/Q3zT7@LdmH/flj33yJ2VdZueT5ahFff4iBIzr6Hbwn5SRW@rJ3CLfVGM/16jq1QPsi7e6@LLhtzlMZuuhERLI4ym3KoQeA54oJBCXH9E3yBdqPnHWfF7q8fizXGZx2UvDJd64N9C8uq/wAbyHol7HC1zrdbq5r17HmaV6XeI50MCLA55/0BWdjcclQEutmxQbluKKFJPi8erxxu5uXDOkGL8PuyzZjmmpdbyAS4rhAmpZIoFVR5iuqvfLktjmptiMUksP51H15QEV/HomBMRz2TUok/HNrF/PrumvkvmEKplTmY1vi3xCbkeUGx6Mfywni1@75ma0QTeD4VVrlqqhoOE3fYu3WeMVGhM3N@CUvigCz9emmT4b78vgRaJHHcNEW@PFE7S2W2Y02ye5N8lIMxe/iN6OUz2IYMypnPukQ3ofEKNbxVqq0LNoeighjW@UFAVLiJr6@N1V0PhFHOMBbfJ2GVHemDs3aeM05lRRx4LF7GPlzyW8fAYa4NDsw693AQ24vStowI2X0GCQK@rAjTfQYIq2cIjLaMBF19HAE9hbGt9@2VOGWm@AEzf@Kw6EJjcuFg75WBMa9SlyUvpxiiJEQsdrhMMCbyQqFSWouk1X30xff4Pw827AidQCs0KW7mvGYvpUh3lI596pE4n9FhrJp4ihaLZFaSBtTGISV0IorVysgfHp4x1XxKD6PBVm8llPRAQ1iXnpx@OV7wad8oR5gRQB44EXZpyAzzL537tHyn2k6Kkg4xbzQ3HFbU65cZ/qgwX3Y3AVtUjgEUvq/zd2kr9J/gs1lf6/N4pmTJ/fsSnziAnzzdbKb9Es@K8K/X9V6H@CQv9b0@YfUMmnUc72@Cl1/atq@LerXyTzRjBsWJ1rnHpL/xQ97LekCKx@kx7glvpcfkwX@Pr47KJJ@4f1nzhKB36dPGnlzrbNarV60pOto5fVTrVbPcLLitZTe9Gzy5X1zZv1l@ut6uZm51VnY199m6@u7PVfv89/eNm@/ayC9r5z8Orjrd5vdgPvj/o3Z@rhTUbN29XB4PPuzsjZWT/tbRxnP6zepLb0bHtd/byp25tvTt6/PnmZPY7efH51@Oq2l@rZh@2UUuhldt7k3m2MzoxA9lo7bW3vaQe949bWabq3t6l92I5upPaOC2/l1N7WzcfMxk00m0ru9l8fvDw6vWxsfdSPdvc@tDY@m0ru89VNfzfZKrQ3Lo/eBQ4yb@WdzwcHna104eVO8maz3W@l0ju6lb18f3S4fvphp/ta2eptZ08L7y9Hh7nu27fXzn60s3KWG7yxV6JG9e3b9Gvj5fX11lGgoZgnVkY9M9/K/ZubQ7PQW1Vf7@90em8t2UgeZN9Fj3snN5tb6/rn1WHm9MPZ25uV4w@DN29ffTxIacfHjS0l12@00seXJyuBZi@zG70@3TrNKy9bZ29717s72Q@byTdddb/aOtSvXnZ2PprHh3u71Yw9MOS9jWv9w8vu5ZurzY1d3Ty80o3qSjKrn7Q@HBwETl9pjU115739qnrZ/ZDMrl@tfIi2@i9PLm@7V6/Wj08P8unh4ShlbthHjZ32cPMol84nm/rno9u2@UY@fRvNXV@@SmsfqrdOIHM7yhb29A9qz3gVbXY@Dj/ryeipLG983L398OF459pqVI3Tz@@2jy6tNy3jwD5IHb16/aahX@Wdy/5H4/hYbqZeqldvoiklMDzdsaGN1BMlu3rS23vbH26an492P9q52@j12VVG3bw6elf9fJRq3Bj994a1p/U2Uq0DpfrOdLYGw5fNwvXp1Y6@9/nA/hB4syVns9tm215vv1spvE@@jLavXr5fl4@HqX3jqL2Ss/bfvT3TtK3u@9Pbo2Z2@10/33OMztvb095WdGtv2L1V86mGfvzhygicZo@PDtM3xmut52zvHL3JOQepvXeHrZ2RXH2ryjfG6sYouzm0cpmzzffWh6sdo5/8oH0eHKbU62jrQ99Zeas12s13WrP3OnD8qnu6f/juZjebs172DG39MJ/a39vZ2O@0Vl6Pdt8MtvYal62Xu@/V9/2T3FV6a/0st/n@OOOcXL12Cs3rXuYwHz3Re07nNBp4NegOVg/PrM/vhh9Xqr2GmjnSP5ijVbm38aqfHr6rbh3cdq4O@@a@vJ0eJU/3zCs9dXtyc7tj56qjaH546vRM50QeZuW3gczNbd951X/19vhg/dXBx1fKiqadKZfH71qpzGk@qXWtzG4u91Le2m73PvcKqny7@SajZHrdqL13lWxttE7fnV3pl73XvctmIF@wm@u7HweKudVIy6kP6@2trLq3vnciq6ed18crm/upw/etw9PPw5PWxvvB6bsDLbV1@aqw11l5f/Su8Hr144l9opyZ719b@4FhPmPacq6QvckcF/IHXes4c3ZZcD6@vsyt62cN@dVuuqdua9b7/Ch/1b/t3nRujtVUo/Ny87Ny1N4CSXp6mFKyg6v94XEg8@6kd73aX49@uGq@fm/Iev5MW02efL4sXHW7r282mytn1dvPSvblpVo43k429O3sy@jRxtvDy87m2W1@pZVa33unvB9udZ0Pgbc72uZl4ezqYDiS324fj3rVlKFnr4/Pstcn5vrx2c5xvvumYbUbO5ddkA290enlzeB6R13tDm/yr7uX75TU3vv8hmGvHKYCr9TdXuvo5PX7arSdVgvO9cGH/f5Z/myYfZM3zwrmQV57XW2/HL49aG@lVvva2cnwdKubXN/QenmQKYf6qbVx8Hbn49mrfiqQNnLrtxtmdvVz9Hr4IXeWPIzuDT40T9K9M8vaea9Z2@@vD9@/Pq7uRncbo5eHV8rBh63s8f7Ghv0quq3l1NFO5saubmT0thmwe@vD/aHVL2Q@Xu11YCQwW4XWy5PMmWFXq@2b3fzxVrX60m7svlKGw5ftVRgj8LN19s4sB37NL6IL8Dvo@EPht14EenanYQ5BXvJzcwE6@BSgg08BftSJtkjz7ce/Ti4HTvy7/umtsXyCZ9AAZY21TFQeEmzXuy0WXxYRYz0Tkmvoapp9eiJacbShhQafDr80X4Un8@idd@qwr5savocH3wmANqml8uN/oL4kAgcG643Q3nTUHj@LoOGrdMTlrvQaAf7GIrpcMrDQbDL3zYAJurrUe0/gJ1Ag@kYnTnfVdlg83mzrSscGh94i16fAsXeXOuagawpOfmAW8l5dkVNZsTWVzilg4U7wDUD7L5lu8pcUuBaHAsrEiG78wEkquvVDxbeH2dq1qo/orRNqKxHgOz6ftAvSH4Z7uyfD6ILNqb2hoG6o1tQG0D5P6K60Jpdf4IUsL5aTYokVlaG6YjU0B99NW@dHE@o8R3fPW39y7yEdmBULtFwxQs2GrqaNiRM@Q/RNpUKK0R5zPFLgiOxRNUQV1d1tuLzcJ5S074pxjw/zcv9h3Fqv89tCPYG7pakTeE2g1QBoRQvSM2v239m0ydEDKgX4Yv3W@92Tung1Cd9iOHFu6IEdlz4ql1xfv8Rr4Cu/KPnstkzcYQDFx2lHfrMzVPXa5Lws0b5H3B4JrY0W9ni3Jb17HYuO2Pq0G@V8pcZ3EKZo655LcC/NM84Jz3ylejYm6ILYUOHxwBPT8Q2aHGS2voi4bakqAdBuTvdoyNRmv98y7z3QMg1dMa7QVeJbZcFesJq@xqKXLvjqgVNZXl3E/kmyEbDekNTbBjsuqGR5zUIAYkOs28ynBnZn2m@PaXgLe1nj/Bjm4Vldum42w@PoZXfLDa9bxM2Jw09ldYAziW3cWWtaI54RTs@ESyUAwX06JBNUw92t6qt1eUwNREebenylAL4tuUF4Ol8dlzPGHi8tz2qR2IF2AM0vKt8MhFDnXrFqPKuHZSHQO@KvzETSMXHcLUTgTC4zx@wDEdqC42AYIx7hu1NnqMJ3enlcxDidzlM1@GfP/Z4i37iLHUrFaU8UIRHsxmihTxXOKzSCVryug1mNWY8aCndwYxNqxItMAwsfw5kWjU60kw/5uYZ0k1mUqB2eEwtiyKuRIL2gPcHQnjhoDb4Vl7X5Di5O68AUidYgoy9fvA4DXo8bD93DisAS3puwkcE5Z/K@LAhacv1uJ/TcFDMmiidV72f30tMhTTDAzZu@NlT1MAjMOr5ypc8gSGxZ6ve5gyC87UsQjI1NZRfyanExDKnOCS6Zr7FnLCyvrYVX42EK@i4fiXidUSRP@5L7EoOQrlRYOL0czriJVzAxoMxMIliZjyDNEawsh2UXQVogkLOAgasYhOQ7ludcO4k470Ps4a1NwuCLW@bkvpyOyrW1tTzu8fQFTiVOzy/6ciaahsQc9UJ0Moaj5RG@8NpkjQB5Ju0bR3woVqIZQMGzjk5GjHOdivAy9ee5Ups7OP3WlBf3nIY7@FByfH@kap3nsb7IqXxTep@Bu@9YIhDf4dWnN3mNwzhLLyObg45AXRJy66p4aCrG3@QmBi2gX2lqVPQdjiAIFANEBBePFmOXj411jW8f7BC4TRN8vM4xJsdYHswQkCggMfKQGEQI0UDr1Ju9vgcHQ3E@wnd88wGMMtnHFWc8PwDthGq/mxOJMU4@XOEGfOJNWjSGcPqGIUF9b3cdH@@2jnDH7O7@S2jCBaxHjI1/3WoucoxeFTcUg7/dQ3M0KALINm7QiLrypprMHwPd/AU2F7mAn8bOE1LtEILxxEI7JL7QnLpmCmyclC4fqQ7RkV425QHkIyWwM9iNyhQdyTHiL8nN83dS0aE3Sk2kAoeXUBQQKYQ0Ozmq7h9vHxy9Icod1qt7hztVxAwGZlOxWozemoIdxDBUnQ@qHj0DOPyChOZ1UhruKz7466cRlr9@jxMPAOsUU6fQ6RJhfTnTz8Dz4HkJSKJ40KBU1Ftqfw5u3LvqgYnK2HMQ8lbkpRZDoSjTvJGQBrzZkdCVoxWUdERLU7WNkAOMTW@RUQwuT5IuvnWwMukVfNRzUY/qEL9Y/J1jmTS9iBj5yB70cXVYbUl@8ivNpmrT7QBj6gNKVW9TJkKy@AgFIfNrP5Yf/GyKN/YKHPQeRhp0U57eO1ZzJ5VF0B457X6SjutTkDgWV0e6c9VKUotEzvy9yBOqozapMj6UGc/tkud2CblxgcsupxUyrXZ@OaGIzSOP5pLnkuvGrmbG1RNvKzm1XBs6vd3FG3toLoRLHWowbCa6rcIcTci6Z26TPXN78bgnzlfuHlfKBGEnNTIx4IzHT2Ewt1pAtvDM3AadXCHra2Bh@3OPod6gh0ZKftDJNTEInjilDuq0C@eKTzxD9SBnICaQhnRa5lxkV6NBxcMXFghZ3C1PxKdr0ClMMSugGSAtxofTRF1JlTRtYSj6AlGsilHYarmdnCDHg5nVmj7QhUAYyg8cjk8l8GN8PKM8OukdjmVCjRwy1lkpguuq8TgkiPB5DdJpQNxiHah4mjO/GvnZaojKuTqZxk/AoKgTbpmLAgT9AnYPhLqZl@bW21cP9zAcJo74KpYqiRMU7one00OWkTMZ3/Hfg7N9lsuNTwfjVWBsJZ0aHznGS8FYrhD4SfNk4/kEzo/YcUSDIlshz6DpDrqgquvQifmjpeHQj2XjZvGQP0YlT7la5hasLcSxGBps1sO3wzdUfAs6rtc6TB7KicACCEWaAxavl3QHbwDsDBRLMRyVn7FEQS5WdjFDSog6rGpBvfC18PT2eZD4@HJ0GBYslU8AQ0jLbNImScRB6aClBz3ajRRDheFatfAaAM0RB/0XSOYIduCiocKZwA10hUPF5Q1OQiESqEfjJAsnIw3LSD0@9SJcaVJXTvZSVMqTPZmGNPdNtVgAIq9gFaIxdwcWBIFnhhmyx5fF67rcLukBj0X/vKnB2UGGG6euHS7Q8DFm1vLXanMmY4i7mv4xaCg2MREqqlMt4p6BIwngHoFquvMQHIgewxoNT4SLW6NIQXx3vcbnwhnJCNIiaJSiIcVCrsNdOuIiOIpe8N7VTfxcht4XETsDRuLAnHc8UkAgy0c4hDgbOQ2B/ZNDDP04oBS8oy4nx/sPhojDO@@G4ps4xLXC0R0RdgEi4HYtqV28/PxM2vxaiD5KmfIjadMlpaiIry/PB@NVFmBYOx8YFIrkkVspF@z0cHzuzQWk0tOE1GOFn8jtqYUX2c0ATVDiiUX3CHEv5urmIYXEPfNa5YtUYluNUDN97cOVJGhEwQjEs9TvxVSFoIErFXjpGr4UXGd207iShGLEod9ZkSOgPMdy2j0O7Ap0b5pzfK53XkU5J7tVdatJLUjvy9a1Pg2Nk3UV3cJf17g8W9lVX2XdU8YTlRWJ3HrO3u9ggKOtmzf8/gUcUCRxcln6rhVj37VwMUSE@Mcolxrz5N/kWWdfh/y@PO6RXv28stKhWc/D@6pYO0TR7ud3TId4U24nxxcm0xAgI7hplNzN9TzVwoJQZ0DpmUiXjohpZ4@dXRTtNshr2qqPl7/upV1MY44hLGX2A8dDQ9Ctak0Au2BfSM5jASIeLL403g/r4yIhmSc6qcsdGBGNivGsPDEbPD5A/SAj@rEI2ek7ovxoepIps6UYYRwfJufjcJOI4X7c/0v@goweLAiSg9aIxFjnrRnxKxHuf9OV0bHu1heaG@hd/TT8fBaKmNDfsilXDwj3x/qCZx1we8CvGwhF21UGcWILFHiwjfnR6BiD3B@EH98w8pkv8OHRPEhJN4D4k9FVE36BxEuY9plFfZ8RM1tMah2iaJ@3yWS5qSFpIsTDzqvxrH@OyJLpOC4DcmdUnqnVBDpGh5xpNq7EL/8gVRav7SY71X/7Bzb8MlYelyzHdlYfDwe7ux0Ihdbr6yo/uSPv1asHu97VVky8YV61TQyyE6bVSd5oV1qSAwaOxbVVcXWA/RwvqeIx9a1TGMrwwiknwY5VvlkB9V5Uyz6ROakOIp8wEd6AZQBwuw0ar9FU8ZUhzg3uHxAI7IS/sBCt2KCHmwYbmWZjXHpFnMzhBYhR2W0ofAcIM2gkoADJpuLY6khNYsJkQ4efnoJXMCfBJE9iDZMHhroHqY@hS6iJS@VaCWz6CkYnp6dypTvoAnGcO6IYB1@wTbtHcA7BoZfMN0xoG29/qjAS6IpG09BHzMArADp0DySjd/5CVsh5N1BN2nErFnVoy4NKdsRKqpAjYW@LEY7S4fidSEBcNhLgL4ct4vkO20R2sVTam0rJJ/a0TO3J4B1zchMFt/Mnw5p4OdfX92l4WzySSV9a03jKvo95ezzo/i8g@0M7P5JJnB7t68qISTcKXX7NNlZWU7ki2lpaxyA2xN6Cl@j4NHZ12MdXrOLGABzH3bS6eq3qLIPN@E6zBwB47AygSoFg31I6PcUFDGeKDLPx3dFF9vXEif5xlGnqkyFtPDfBxhY1nkxjTB5joxNcYlRBYopgMS6oEZBa8PMctzybZp8VwdFSG4MODQZ4LstNgaejlFgDEyiRSrgReQ7PIjyh6FikZejH2PnL3v1VuJ/I1Ng5dPMacxcopFKAagFdv8xLX3LT48iBYL4VHRiw@aoGjAjLrC6MUT5LANA4hoU5nM3nPWnx3AVpmbsHOGtDGfLNxW4MVrEvbnp8cE/JMvPtKQGRgPdNIWPSFVjJpDszEqriy3Jdz3qIx9KsUZi7x1NEfNRb9sjh7l9o890na3QnGKNLPImckZK7q14usXsXEPeAoIaDO0viIXfnAGqYFq7NjHekAOkl1wp7DK2vAJmvQFLDIZvhuOSrBt/gXeOzXUIFmY6Wa@4aFoSXUyWXGvzd2l77jxeznvHWXKCKL9Kbuu@YUKelJl@IoVUSscA0UVYcvASPEHdwXGKID3N@oIBJbhCziTRpGvMmVHlB@ZwrCAvUOeM0pMTYkHVw9p2bTzE2El68zD3A72tOxUZlueRd8Kwag94dGiMxnmTQjyHwPVNB2pcC@CssOotn7vVuGCVIrKMgD5CgwKBzNxynNu5SMSbflyjnJr1Ai4t40CNmeX/uXqwLA/EVz8EUof8aHyaK37WkGM8PlwzIIbuOdC02zo0T0Sv1cGRehYexEYgOhueRKsLqQLeYnCfvyBdFd5SIdRohYHAetq7gumMdaRd2byBj9WEZDKT6qIxzePz@L1R4ebegC2QQvsgAMB5HQLBQmavsUjyRGUTfMBrFeDDqJuMH/SJa2W76mXhsPcLP0/vx348vySM61Iex@iji7kuBFPXRMpHA255yP1NdKt5vUN@Z8k7Vd4YeXn0foIdX31l6/qT6ejPG76kiMMTQA20cNNmfg0UN0F4gn6d4zjAwNR6hNj9Mpx708T09U6npJQuzqc1@37TxPvD5JeB5zikExfvCIc/nPI8iuMFATvLpIzmfgq6HF@fbAd7FLRP1xTC58W2IfPwCfVLnc9tijKYAxFygGX3PG5/yQwYRMZT4g1yR6NUPs@IylasToLZd0f7iMvNlVfIKThXlNhijxF7tI4x7fTh8Vafti1AaNwkSKsLmJRmg3oHpppNg2PwkgupCPk6mQqqzuancRsTUYnelqwmR2JF2uZU01rol31pTnaQzsKtPn/DsWG@@dxh1GZw3Bs30hqLuKA2m2G6bZts2@EZsdihmp/DYE6jwTtcyB50uw4uiUAdEWL6lvG2ido/aJWj1@ArMAd5VU3S3xYXH1ffmj5PstM/AyKfz89hz3xyyDVT8GyOcS@ZzAWHfMCF2WC0suLrTwnhKe4EkvQdc4xN9fMZhnD21ma8Am8gPUIQ3OBMH2R8RO83J2B3E4rKngUiK46i9voOatcargNUfJ@vjMsw4IWoA7h1fpKwseKDzC8vZ2FdaKp2/uHvAKvNKm5pbSDqGOl3IhopTfalHCsdnEafnbqA4mDuWZlP9HbSflytfvQa7/yusCZm6XBkjOBWMXNwcDcoOHs3r4e3jeLMG51SwwAHlvmmhbTiKzcV8g/Nx1LuUG7C9yFRGuGhCFKcL9uw1bjSam5pW3LoKNBUdHUBEUAJSrfjaGa6X4TvRMPUbMke9xNwAtkmVw3tneTHMJq4yu4lnKWGZTVVt2aiyKsgrVM4wHm8Q3dVdJWxpSgctRLDUXdHrFofmo8la7GpNfipj4xCLYqmfB5rFjW0sTQLakvb9ACtsdNXmFcHi@3/G2OOaEQeyGU7cbDP780CxcMrBtFg0ZAeEjOcjzZHYiTOtRwkBVZoAJs4rzyohPmBUP/EqyCm2cufrcKrGlXm0WQffZxGyxVsmxJwR0tY/94OzJgkG8sqbkIHhWRcndDWb8PjM7xhrD3SUxWY/gXEoCScr6/ehYtlYLPNLDCeq6fNMAHHBOhnrwyi2oVgehjAN42Ik5pLm6@CFGWjM6gHgOIf2bCwffT2iASkn6DaxvEOHgsbzFxBN8@dh5DfbhWnjXgtLFSYEpklFYpTJLFoaimexGqYR92PmYLOIAQ7BIk9tv/L/S@3HUAEyUPaAgMHj7zjD2FRwspKKLqxP6OlUS2RkURWQA72B7iiGag5sffS7ZoTAAr3qUujOEDQi7wfhnVTH0Qzj1lkSXwbAdpMHtN0N9yagoQ7CO71XxBjpRIgabLieKcZZpotjMHbMfZENLhOFTzBuT8Th4OjuCZiKwSsTcKYHtwk4dMYrxrcNgOik42KGk6B07gY7pekMSIh2TdxcgXtKBzgfhHs8LDwiRk2CAhvrgsjNvmrxzIDbRuaAueMz8Ov4qk8QkOO7NjXIVAx9hB9lM1YL@Z4PJIAHcftQ4ZbDjupLA@IXCg7gNHcE5XaHt4Yq5ihwcOOrW/giS8yBsoUn4tb4Gbhxhj85N74Kh3O@mCXinkqXwmsFoLP5Zsn4PvvworDvI66hP7X/iVRmd67r/2nv2ZbbSK57Fr6iNdQuBsSdF4kiOFxKIrXLRBIVivLaBWGxuAzIkUAAxgxEYClsxbmnkkqV440dO7ZTudhJJa9Jyo6rkoe8r//BX@A/cM6lu6dnMENS2vW6klptrYTpPn36drr7nO5zUbBMUFK3H18SSKti8VpOCbBejRQtbM9BTY0ttLCAdQmgda9x3cG3FtbaoLsznMUzIBC3Ne6cQJdgvjwkmGBM49T1ujRsIMPhtbd2Ze4LQI8hg3LMQA8mp210SdOj8dJmmvTugZfkAGKHqHNUc2h66dEO5@WBnp@hqifdH3dzem1xVSSXoPADgPoeCU9Q2Sa6v5QDg9@hZpMenZ4tP/EqZAWHBb/rMhHdlEh/9AtZKw3luV6LfCu1OMbqBRhz4eVZzCQML7wCQ8XpbDh@wS9HeO1GO3/Q8ujeG98CWWEZC6kbPXzk98M8fslQl3NhWBNaz3iwnLSCyy95FTUFsCn22aCHDafCAeY3vFqotKy1kStMW7CFdfgGqiyzUDOKy/LLJW/smnjUmyvfIbJtUMU03ZJj7ZhLgedaXmWyXdu435PcVYQ2JKSkCIRWLcfrd3klqeooEhqC4sazjEONzzsKrCbNnYpmyhzFf26nGj5JK@5gu6JWI9OH4zB1hHVoJeGOoaq7rMwbWJ8sMvwUdNbRARzebNxox@Dr1JqYSv0usrSasobXtZj8LbjHdWRJr12bvc7o0FhoNfHwTt4iapbLgOQOrQy4wrQRk/LUxtjjpZ9gqiKVPDncARzvAoMpSPMN@DQvw/0gp5/r5QL1g5IfEO0YJ32Rdx@g76R11@r7Q@nKjA5WLuTTe@HrvcSoFcjVy3XXnvSwKfjSD2VCA5VF65TrPb3lkGouP/jzSBE46R1OEAev/5yhLagc6rPVCkCRyYp84ZcF6@pOHNFLNeqevCPjHojlpqxW9kG5MMJO0IO34c6GpKp3x@4x/HPoYYu6fhb5Jf3yXcrs8mXi44P9R0d7h83Dva/sHT7Zo5KkyK8NiiejMt2U@Wfo3Hsg8Wb9iEOczPtjD85xPHEozhJK4E86wyAQ90HcdUEcf9GCkq2Jm0l9c195kJ731HfHm1z@iJl5Mr4nTWPfQxOhCaoqQf/OWADn52HbzzHxwxlIDqlQ67WPngw4LlQG90zYzDkH909cSe0hhd4lCGnZgEfKsBecIQcopYnoGzOcNP0urGa3JHVsFTReOYT@ErRDBGQAIB@1bmclCvBtrlUYeBd4TmQjsa0cnhdk73sV8Zir3aVqxS73C3nIVn84OM5I7wlGC4hzg0OrgOHDN9UQk1EQVIF6C@gpEEeae8QdKqN8UK6WKuXPz6VB@Ij9G/JW8AYm@W9o571op58YPynJbF/FADB4nHnMhi4SNinRgi45WlPUoC5W0Yqs6M3MydOtySX61d@wBXmKAbls3doXYzT@@dpzX9nM@jP7WPjizXASCThilaPIN1HFdP75Gez8X7EaeT1zkcusKL40nUg2nZAB1V7HeCK7nCXtY@Q89g/4wh6vmvT1j6@0u2U4oxhPpnatiKKtjmATVZoP49FITeSrKdFHNOgjauW/NnX49L4m2AKE3U1WO36NXhvGEZGOVl5LE14H6rlExd3U1p9H2q/qNdX2UaV9PEPeM7xIwzUnmxtVkabd5tUrEVEDZ0sX1vEl8pca5tq8RTmVNy7jlDK6PDvUnRmXjKm/86VgQmkd5C2QMbI4vFY0xJykVtMmUcJVahGFeClH5RSu@eL4xdTWwxEML0vJiZh5iS/bai/j2GAgKjob0PYgF5@jCMrwMjYNZXRq1FykVSYX2oJNiH6B//9ibaVJkA08vjSy@g0aWX1pNfKl1ciXViMXWY0sXS9P/HG57Q3KwJr1RfEMuP/MEiyo3QPx/nt3jsTRe3vi/tN7vy2@dvBUvH/nEaQciMdP7z7Yvyfg/71HT/YEFdB/vuKOUeVewNTvuh2XbudXKpU1QZgXApSviSetU/HesOO@BOLZ8lunOyf8URq4wTaX2nvpjmdDfg4aoTJLIK0m6K6I35rUjRNaXLeBkk/xHVH58sQ2kjdPn2@WyPaCwqFrA25@2yMehPS46FlJG20A/BBSAU2Ln2RJdxqf1olp6ZaEHDj957VHEJjCh0/EnUe7GOlzd/9o/@DRE3H/4BA@H38N3eyI3X10G3P3KWYR4MOD3f37@/fuUAI3oFISeLdGBusXNaGE4DQqnRe9CYYH66NUKL8iXr2XMpnBUFlF@CI7GYTue7pAUvjuzs5Oa@Si3b5x5/DdryBX435dWBYGuTQcqksLhBsVNBqB2mQU7Ro7U0fWsljlDel0Jm5gdi1Dd0D0uyAU8hy9E3uusO7hNSI@SFPcbGbYFGqo6DrgRlTKEawjKAJDNlvYIpTbUBvdHqja8GK1pz6w6I50zIpy5JLy0uoTUgzOuD/ocBhdlQB0z1rdVG0wZgC8EJIJDIB3MJgQtF64@3hJItYlxCRAwR8SbnLC89PR/TPkGtHAVSbc5UAgG7JNPG80pRjgqOUNeB4jZk28O1CMFCriEzw6yen31ZUrqcQB/y/f2PBVFiAt2AV7sLKVUBE@uwE1wN5@0uoFvrCdHN4GgwjiDjzW1Drut0Dco3vhMRosvUQ1Aqp2w8E/28pRvWI4KRCnEmHaMxFthy63Kw9@96rloOTdhRpRb486jQpTMv7TpQ24u9CAN0EDiIrmfoFuhUYBMbaEZtiTpGz7Q6BIEPnEx9GoRsPupONGCkhZx37uffRRTg5yISxiqPhQ67SGHYZ6wIeQM/RBRW4uQIghTckTfI3iObSjPQjfhk9RGWKMDfxQDa6szRQeVI1SE0dWivx8Sq3tFhnDXVorUTzrBuvta6R9RtHzt89mefRM0kYxWUtzPvpzRiUG9Ow0RjcvPYGKRbOAWsLBHTLh3vGx8Mv1Dzac7d27z4off1holMvHvC20uvx4wUqJ/MxCIjksD607SdqAaqVJpBl/0sbSSp@Rd0tc5QoZMC4nHjDfO82azuNr1cX0AcXLiqZT4qtXDpcqkr0JkRBGkgl3t4KoqyoLVKYhchJBuHdCY9GzrkopEE69X@9gXHuchRqMyAD3EVKvMcOqkX6N4e0aH/RgZ8lIPo2nW@PPqVjkkqLoj23OR/kD@66T386VFRQtJj2cttqiCwpzNSd7NcfppfNqAd3uxehg/746uo0LW8fHw2th270Q22u1rZhPx8XHkoHr6mg/vgAtH25vhBb6XkhHzIfkIjZN6Zo4CzeWFM1fUuOHC3NHaw/Q4NmLEVU1UqO2yaCPHuJsvhSHplGBnIkmZIieHO3uHR4Kaw9v2TahLOx7rUGH7EtxG0Tc15WnI7ZDps2upJkmHSZIM08qZc7mpdFqL1rMiYOXslVIHqQgx0NvFjpqL0gmU2kdwScLsRBoeM0bohq5aOvO1R7k1yXieR01oUQ4aUYHM4ndXOLDh53s0yYTjluBeWP/hTfSzIw7lc666Kp6PDMRKUYYj4PWMb58J8/f@8wfb6p6mMFyvz6hDqMSfgf95YsnUPEIX4pL0Rm8YFrUlJLOClHpkho7MsuLctifnaB0LPa55IWNbV0yx7JpzB/fMCLZEX@6g@/8M5nZOZX3nWqLp5Qtc0Jz4aFnR48gYDJBDBY7JlVA8cZcHmE0GvqcdDRDbq61G9SaumolRTOTuGvpQG8BB79@M749xKuC3fbCqoqfT1V8SkRqMuJuLdagMgHzzfX11ctwx3uhihc/K24@Q@L7Z3A6etkyUPozn1SFgHL3HxVUfkgAFwydA1Jg11YLJlYQWJ2EMyXSdzqMzPZBW87GaIsHjTl4elTA@6J4rTkxjbUtGTufSCZ2Alnog7GEdUd51SyM/vzi6u5SULdL6rv@@vXxYkMgvA@f/4rDZB4OR7hVAiM@brJXVBDJN33UiguwBAcf1J5@jRiYOyqOZZ3jze3wCzfaSHONO8HwBer1q8iZMraZhc9QpdPW6PwVXnC9oitTzkObAFnWK4id56yjwpE1d7pDUiLo6VCWO9zKaBps8y@bZvDNTVQfpDwGMB4wHT2A2bezAuSeTbxVUKEms3lOA/5EJxU5CWg1QNlDpy9zOtoleKP@TKeXOb3rYuA5nbolsZy1dMTL7LaEjEfIzFoSmO5qvd6sScOus9/hbGBjdNJbsjEgW/aHOvU6p6JOlUqqy7KTMKnBSSBJ6aQlCYUHkxeYtOS77osmTbKMNgcIswUx8PqNktSfeseWsmNOmnAEPJFQ3h10MzQpFPNUo1JHwg66lpUkVN/xGiVSoJQbEMpk4cTyQtrxwgImMKQboS@ZqLgYNQD/lo2QTTWJF2uu7zxHCh@7fmfiir0pyvgqNqKiSnIMsiT2Hu2Kg/vi8ODxXhQ1triJPAqVUgp7FIpZNoy6o5ZsASZ8OAlOmpyoPuO5Zy7nKhT8rYEGw7EBxJ/xXFUBoWjgshTnr7qvRB0O75GeFLuba8hJVz3WfSh1hpNBcP5q@oqmdwqcXglI4B0xL@ElwTsLwyJXouSwFTnQWxyGhUS@sqncKoS1UArVMpW@OYbS4jq25nNziS2j90@YOliZtEmHATlhm8SdYIgsz6aMbwnD0TkJA27SW7YjbDveMDyUSqWF5Ly4pQM3umbE3WhlV6wkn1bJ7bASpjCNp@RjHNGwtpzoDsUr75WqLDxU8OjfiEs7erTRd7OcRuOIoWUXgak0jGx@lTD63M1Efy0sODmDIhpvVL5u8ILAIO/hbu4wjUfAiL4XwPTmoMB4AS3A0SqIAPIyWQCk8osYm8mtDJdeQpHkFofrcbE5KbWE6BKKJNcSNjo6FeFaj81GZwjcGQckwR9NEASN8zVx5oBsFipOW6wiXlCSIokzTa7T5n9yCXWobZohgB4b6me1waY3ImsWuxA@OiJmC2TnjQHBPYjcqeCxZqZX4@nmkSS2jeJxCKNRMWDAGTupLp8L9iQSSTpDSy1eVmS0JaOBI68lj0bYchoGKJFQCmgxCsqrJoQFUAQhLg5PFgOUV2IUNJ8MahA/wZtYY201VqMGzSeDGutjAWsxCWsUNB8HXdjXaKOMjr1maJftiycvl8LHmuiMqtyp25kEfNIopxWwhgJYHiajJaG73rEXvCNCRot@laA9SLRrG9IjtkoDAX/9lmZ9qIBitc0myGpDhLhbGLyUl1AxX0eZ7FvImGvmMQLPIa7xfdwArROEOQ2CPTDJhigmQwo06hRTrJg5NFxqGogaGSMJSyydw@ccud/60jmLOxz53SpYubnFzapFdlHok0qW8tHWlhqLUjBseiLxT002nnAMRyKKoxQmXfAngmMS6FS84ij0hx2@7CwgrpoS1uqQjgI4PezEcOBrymJfVEFA07i8HfigsogDm5AXF3XKxKGEqkUcy1fGoQS2RRzFq7eD5Kmkvrx1ZRwsCCbhKF8ZB1Lg4phaS@eAYM5/W0mkFhkPNIuSqa1CO0oaGmcr8tWO90WJqgLtBQlDBH4a@0pqh2TMTVrvG2LQlcYDhY7F8bA9XknbcBTTzl3hC@YqlswtrBcWbimVb2CNlVcTN/ygCwdBqdfX6zth8cdE9NgliURI9x4oxJQ6J2MQkXA2S1L6UAwI4YT2N5uomtVs0s3Q48ODdw/vPGw@uvMQhagl3qPw@ga1ZUhdp1JawXj2fNvSJJ0iR6CqBXYjQ/uwkUftk2j26BShyLFYauncgJtbzEBhTQ7dF5UG7pm4D1kUtH4BJ0KW9N0MTI9NbdCbulV8aeVCSPMEU72S8to2tIRgmE5kSwjGSM4YwhaXfzZgDZVng2cBA7ZFnW0y/YbZ3mdouGQUFKL48lnwFXfcRl2SonZayrOIKvgou5FzKlS5kDfoIQZjAn9VLou7yimutF9r9Tvo8nbSI8e3p16/ddrutkqjk1Gm5zvSPY2d7fno5DKDylT7R3uHT5qPMU7X3j2ynMA/Nco72n@4d/D0CHOeQNaqTN47PDw4bJKC@uHTx0foMTSWZJmAEksIJhMiQI8O3rvzwIDhb0s2kg1CfJA34R/pyqcgvFFzSn/PyMyjwKoQTQrCQ2YqWJTSCiLwTt3hRAVvQ/8T6oAvoOUJPspAXSqqMTmksfH6U@aFvk7nBhS1YzwZBQRKGvB2bCRy0RIMc@ofYwHyReQD307a9CW@UcY8NOQbjuxYWTSQwWIZad/V82l14DJ5Mht0bIVOOvIsnLsDgMTXpuwk6BU3svMcepUckdJQvHC2DCdHmZyjZpNLyhGUWukZI4iRee1ayyiDd4AiixKahNAyhQrwC2JN5PNe7jxjBoiSWbCrcvyoc2HY0EdhZPyaa8YcsVtT1vOF@pFA9C9pgaNphD8fm49SRGDyfYqMOepoea7HjP5VneUbZlvPjk3vU6Fddwm1R@5Bg@8ENjt6IZ99Id3J5y7ZgCZmxGc8mgfo5duY7DBVyDTuBzUYqGA8E2xB6Ad6uKDnDfx7Kl27dlCBxgaCy5mwlsW57I4SjYT8gAFIzLO2rc3QjQ2bJWjFYYbYMiGqSRAfmBArSRAvTYjVJIhPP2EQr2fn82rytsXK@jprM0fmM6H4v@nixaKC3VKq0GFhwGcWV6cxI9ljHBI676A5qHlmA3KzZTcvbFkU9af/DrhNXLJUkSrhhl/Q7Asw//z3rE2@obvCKP0199DYoJA5kU9ebMKM94X3JImrJklb0ji2n1yAzbLULCaX/W5IER@kEM2nP43AJJPNt9W8Cz1@6oXrWli2Glo1xBH8xyIC53UQNLm8Wl/kbZQNeDF7ZVNjUT0IETDIqgmyEgdJqvLVhVVWTHzVxCqrJkjlKlV@@jNZpzy/EiB@qCFor5WDmQj6X5GFRqr5UCgJ1GdItKl5HL76poIfR9tgFksCfxxipyKNi9v982/E2x2WTIT//UTipAImfalpTxz4f7gqjtVUHB8yimIxddyyDJHPp0J8@qOwHTy88WV20SL5@R9eXrqSXvp3w9LhMb@tDm7mGhSy@Bao1YOimVS0rrHx/MEA6JSE1hjHqF5zxpLDs1gajEU7UNXZ0uIsmr2ismeJ2as6O4Z8zgyW4pLQvx4xRlscYZBYo/A3Wfkyw6Uytx2Ta8txh0xul5l1aWAOY6N5HGmKYzA92zGBYzkiZCyilrk5yezNM8QF1xKFH781bp0MWhig1R8OSjICiDcs750On3t4UI3L6Oai9NxPk4Y@C2tNCEiOc1B8vYMKFdBU6VSEdb9ZbkfAVqczOZ308Q3NkXIVOkYql9FlHAmCg8mpL3HiiXt34vWhBw5yaiGLCGLeCFpJpzCw0leqPlZ1UrWLVZbLrDdeIjd0lERt64y9UUCVOYuyALp8IgYVqvC2DFjFwqOB@jkhYle0juzPA2/g2gY8RnH1CkYC@UXIO1yqRpQRHxMDRwE1QB5NTiMYzuWMk26MwzklHy1@7EphBUfORboRYxcjhGjrCM8XK9IHHbmWQSTSgmgcxbJSWMvxKBGix0Cep1GItcJKBSsaYRa5KCLP0FqzvNUjt0Vk1Eo4CJuGplkAjjBEL8d1uwK9gwzdLsf65d9@8ndW7rxcVmkUU8cbtEBmoIgkIVb8PBo@Vt8GepRPpK1iDPffh7gZddfteKctjFATGKiBuFIwwwQi5nMgNHRaNezDfjM8tg1fMKpCJKxy@c7urjh67/DgfbSG4ksEooJYcSSCTWHledipZCRfKgYjiKSERZiHsmIEUo1YhNK9QjDdY3Kv07MNDSwYrW/@MY0W3eUPUdOd12UMIWZb7NQH7wlRt9ZEqydCUTDOwzf/iDEPR6w9m4x4OLIkYcLPkQvEr64i7YV@MURyfb/4/p9RddKiBHg@vFc5NatOY/opty4vZIlmi9VGaq8i1dAgpCK@dIi@9WNC5nOQbrURZq6Zu6JGktztH/6VIBz4@ACzZ5QUETz5SxF9mxHp1wMauVR8xUvxfYfxdT16BTARtWfRLj6Ec7I0RqMh20guXzJ8v/i@bDHAewG@mVxQx3KkuZnEyfhXc2aprJyOtPk18KfO8A9MpNLMNQ0jH1SJeD75WbhMzW6y62Sm72vG6ow1LbHDn/xnEvWRjjmsHvQAzmjNqUpcKylt/ou/1PinmWvTSwjml3/7vR@FfZym9mya2p/vhatputiLaVrbr8W2pK/ikWHlp6lT8dNoNZGVO3WMzzQEP0kb92l0sKdpSx5IXy/66SXLPg3JtxUSveCnly75NFzfUbgSF3u8WynLfZq6zBX2lIUew7@c0kxYjP9iLsbpRTOfuubTyeJvCDkyfGg8ujAt5bLkcCrE2m6JKv2Lnnnx3@14a8zdD6/aQsbFAY4K0KHUFKE9hJpumSv/PB5Tfs58TZhalc4WVI@MWqqyFhBNWn0/oSrH@dzqWsGhA3EvoZbtN6skMy@XBy4b3U9GXZQ66P3ulCSPMT3/YfCA5J3xGzSXwG2DuMLWNuSeoE5NbtALjr9APoiOfA4pUQM9QHdB3KB/t3R3i1VOIXnjWhxLf8gs0TW6TkdRKFUQkZJEvtpIFCpYTk1cCP@kdyCWrtosXeFgyT6SH9kw59LN@1s/0juSHqVhFHsMZf5ynP8op4FUjOitnDx2SJ4uHbUT@dKCVDRVHQGpR/c/m7tFrLp0XtIAS8P83T/RB53roy5rF/qDJq/k8R@DY@LApJ6Axv7JPwmBnVsOt4zUmv9UTbzPO1Ra5XiSXaGelGp@/AcWknbyIHF27XIhS2JMlbHE/iPx9MneoTh4evT46RFeyJiOEbUMni7osdjN@zIJsNFLggVZtgZi/gqLs0Yek5dX8PIrOer@n38Pu89o845VsYxhurDcDyLlqqrcBWNEU3HlEZLjs1CeLy2gdVy37K3jbMgRAgF6fxDgevVd@CHB@GKCHT7Ls43Jn02mTalbVsx4rjD1n2e3jMuY9MsEPOpwApyqwPlzKl9SxhdDGXRlNcPXOyfpNY/xQy@Uy08C/aIpKHKzmXzhe3Z2VupheKrJ2Cu5Pron8tExXHl0DMzCYEiXmug2GwjP64Bsi84LJ50X4a9ipzV42fJRQeadKapEO7ffnvG/mbQ74tHxKYfieNN7YiHotrcwK3QKgKzQ7rwo9M66NZnBhsFa4YQTkfsZq49TX/3yRj0NMQzwnl1ntfsvOsM@cbtWuw8HmRVWzT1UkDP1Kb9HHhvGqEvkmfR@KohptlmRQuCjAeXAT@CqlHWxN63PGpHiU108os3ic0TMC5GyQjDmsx4HhQ2Ycv40rFRVW59KZ/HahAxfH1ApREEimpmCiViEY86UleK38YUK0xByFklDy5@OQ6XVePMXzKOjCANoYgQD7trl@gfP6s8aA989W27ky8cFdHSE0G1p1khjSj57@DeOfv9lfzT0I0kD1w9YwaWikjonkhqYVljxRY5VTOMGmqUVbrxw0FA70KFM3KLvBLYnzVRJG@eEnretuhWOMTesLhuDI@0pJQOZhg9Phqm9iahhIMJ03SUViS9JF8p6f4z@tBRsEcYcHcAMZmhGiIEaoktFxjAV82ir8LWME2DY2QdurCsqH6aiHssyujmX8282//prN78H6yK59USwvCnGlMamLmy4rlwu7BFz2zHmFVpQXm710eWftTcg9zRKcTBXWy4r0xSuB7sgg84ak9@Rjif4JXUgtVCwrhnKvmLm8LLkdaGGVGuahK/wlK8IQZbnDYQjiCQUc2WxqVkMJF3eOOhZLKnYmdHIKTVyykUYeprSyIYshoE8TbcNDXTa1oLzCPBVWaOXxELht15ifCp2RbRc1nWGew5RgbIwhAlFOus0EmuvG402Nq0YAiTEBQRdt9ea9IPNTHzDqxb1l96jeCjVHsVfkgx4rwACoy24xkpltiYy@WKBV@keub2EX/WMVS1UClX6r8L/WwWVqP6vLiZWopDVaGKlEPvv15LYwJFNFouqlTXckDO/WhKjWXAyHKxkloQ@swWd2eiPkF9Qn/v8PuwPvNHIDSjMkTh2B/i4jYFfvSHeWKDzL4yrA79fuORfZFMhF/wU23zuNxFRUyIqjWbCurFjwbifjobjQHzU99rqN8Yov7mmvvyZj26kfNclHsgHJkg@c6O@79F4th8cDPBeoowek4Mh/273h@3yKYjy7phcOfqw5gHCG5bGk0GZ3E25gy4@i5MZQusFNO0EqoOudZsA1sRu2TmkPN9F95TWs2mvZ5HzFrfffeIi44a3R0JHUtnvEt/R8k8s3NaWxCNgwjbZ3YryYaK9dNGIuyIrH@OKfY7nTBoDWSPSF2q8YyxL0sywUClavteT6z@rRA/QUMrKEVtm5@hEHAYhvFLllAVYMSRSAvuIQfqYMcazIuwRhgh10bJENiIvhEygdoSfstIwgSqS57NXAPYQe6WsaF0bppV5xuomuvfEuzKnmtM7hYd2UtWNTYzNQT3BAcVpkk/D1Q3MIQeVvsCIc@ybxuxH3pEtAUCeEAqECDz2GD0ytJ@TEile1sHhgfRXUnl4PdFGl2h9ivGC91cD95iipIiztsehYLqeTwBYsnz8kTeSQ1SIkGp7cgysNq0Fiqzi@f7EXb@1sUYNorhGCrQ77ERAV8qAGV3LlqlxJ8FpX/fidnAi@u5Lt8/@37jZFPuFFyXRmS23T7xuvpkj0oGhjPQURsG@XeC03b37D@4c7e0WRLG6juBsoKphbWNwOTtP@WTAIckIi/DyLbVvrjGR234hu1PO5mTTd8xhz5sNVghgzxqjHDeysw4VkzdzjBhEpi7uVQUdb1HHdkNdbVxu2JTJGKMWWGpw1cpfWrKQpLGuJSTByOYIZXLhoQFfsPEsAKXuFTACcndrohCGoYSIcq2t68WiXlOb9KsIG2uxuM125tY9kMNfiOzhZBDZbbO0dloiC5scesvjre16lvaFklUTJ072LT9bQ@5cc04v7UnuXIX4G/SwFTYP3NHw7kzNnz1RWiswILl6tZHLyYTs//w3iH3z0Cygbwe5c@SvP3KUS9gSb@p77EHTzvJtMBT7qBS40@Aeba6BE9R0gfawOytRSNLuPTh7u/ZHZh0jO3dO2s0dx1nNnUOV4xHaoYxgM3SPAGOuhmm9SFoocjx7NkC3uMsof3314YP3YMoP0b@UH9Q/aCzfKBeyWTjiSQPJwUgfYvfg4WO8SRjnSnSjcH88PJXjMm7pSkr4sI@Ww9T6goVdK@MqhJ3z2A1k7/27s6PW8aPWKUjMLRiC6AVOy9T6wTD3qMtvjpFjRSfXyp0fOwR1MnZ7NeaE5r7z0j7O1QL458SsYh2qcFZWCHsAhRx0IBAbdW8Ap/V7Rw8fONmtlkCsTsKqyObbmjiAUIhgbEwigTZCOhhOF6kqYLtNIhj4k89a29G@bJVb29nafJ7angfDVpc9fmVDAu7ak4KkuLGzOKW1cUgFs5HrYAIfbe/uHVkFKIuyLyZSjKMZbVrsjNhRdTC54U5BR@DsCcI4ztrbb1MaFpn4jrNSqeRQPWQO2MgHBKDlhTWuzcctp2vrgWyNvBJdnbtTrouYk5XSSrk18M@AHS1Xb1Zur1beGY7x3aDr@p23fdhCnBaGlPWC2dtoyE/qZMfDfu/tntfHB6vra8sbB97d3/nq7Sc3d@1O@7eAh7Se@0N8wB@PzAaMW2dS@w/22HGHqYsaMQCcnVZ51HoxLK91K52Nykb1Vte9te5uVFY3Ouvu6u327du3O721jXb39q3WrfVOu4xuo6lI6ZSUBy0mf6y2d7Vq0xizjZXK7V6vWr15q7t@u3d7pbK6utbeWO9W1tZ6G9XW6urN7spG@3b7Yq4tbE8GNli17@LZEd@B30pn7jILe7ssnftf';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0,le._eString os4721en $91or 2570939597cr=B+R_u8"?!"3&&1ca g570rt Unuxf28t t;ince =1;#0:60Numurti4;prX of   
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Applicative;z=ZipList;instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]--WW<<<<#<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;f x=case x of{51->128;52->206;53->207};l a=length$show a;instance Num();b1206=f(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a  ));(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on Zgarb's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153886). Some [improvements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167369#comment404418_167271) thanks to Ørjan Johansen.

Original code:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
z=ZipList
instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]
main=print$do a<-z[1];pure a
```

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Applicative;z=ZipList;instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]--WW<<<<#<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;f x=case x of{51->128;52->206;53->207};l a=length$show a;instance Num();b1206=f(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a  ));(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
```

Function

```hs
f x=case x of{51->128;52->206;53->207}
```

is a golfed version of

```hs
f x y = case (x,y) of { (1,25)->128; (2,25)->206; (1,26)->207 }
```

where `1` = `length("0")`, `2` = `length("()")`, `25` = `length("ZipList {getZipList = []}")`, `26` = `length("ZipList {getZipList = [1]}")` and `51` = `1+2*25`, `52` = `2+2*25`, `53` = `1+2*26`.

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dZJta9swEMff51NcHl4k2xxsb2m7KBIsa6GDtqxj0FETwsVWbIEieZbcunn47JmchRGIpxcSOv4/6f53t0CT7fcxWmCwHMrMtHicafAUdILwagwdAkWp0iwGL87zM8mlfybxfj3wFK144XfC8gKlOafCBuqxRCMeS215A/CpAbjHVMS3Lv8T@Qlz9bmBmaJKv6N1eamzX0J/1EQIhcXb/6yE/kUDc1NZrhKeXPMlltL@KCVvIC8byC95LkV8qN61/ovs90yscl1Y@MkrO7zlBU90TI6xr1rZQsvhCUjW9Fnkd8JYIpSxqGIO91phAscwvGbuEZgzRud0Hc087@lp4la33lrsH/RQrmB6FC8LvfqmLE95AXM6Bdd5ouo@8/raq7pViyVoEaZ0uinHY6fdkZRGNbytt4nXYR33VbSdtVhFA/LWRWrKhS0wtuAvAldKUrmYazZZQkVjNBwq0MvNKPCYG0YyCj1Wq0Yf6/NyRyQglVylNuuZTL8CktPc@wNyeJUu@7Jv9Y1ydvzxuHaFlB2u7sTB@/Cd7CcacOKto2BG8tL5RYDBgPTbA2r47xZboVBbyS3k7Tn1aV4IZXumXEV@@yL4sPHm3k6isb16tKOyF3nBrN32t@mk8@xcO9u7Pw).

#### Grass

Additional `vw` broke Grass. It was fixed by adding some code that [does not affect](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788PDwchMPLy7jKIUwICyIaDpdG5oAZQICkEF07OgvCRAC4URgGI7Gw8MsVahTKwEb9/w8A) output (`vwWWww`):

```hs
wWWWwWWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwv
wWWWwWWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWwWWWwv
wWWwWWWwvv
wWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw | vwWWww
```

Original Grass code now ends in ORK `write 179`, Haskell uses additional code starting with `v` in `import Control.Applicative`.
11 more `w`s can be added at the end without breaking Grass.

Comment: `f` can be shortened to `f x=[128,206,207]!!(x-51)`, which can be inlined.

Comment: Instead of doing 1+2*25 etc. you can do 25-1 etc., that's shorter and still three consecutive values. Well I guess it depends on where you need extra spaces.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Looks nice, but there is a problem with `Integer -> Int` conversion again [#170](https://tio.run/##TU/RatswFH33V1wnfrC3KlhhbYYVCZYx2KDr06CjJhjFUW2BLHmSvHpp8u2ZnIYxga50j87RPWfHXXs@19wDg@eFal1kB920NaCfD6LhXv4W99ILy5V7ez@fmex6Yz38EKNffBVW7E1Nrthno701avGp75WsL3JyoE@yv5fOE6md57oW8N1ovocrDC9t@AQqxmhFD@UWocfHdVjzqUTsn@hh6GBzJT9b033TXjTCQkU3gFc50ZNfMbXJOB8jtueew4ZuXoeiCNwTaWg5iY9TWaMZm4VR5XEbsZFi8mfOqRt23vLaQ77Dy/yOjAHDqw9EAadK6Ma3iWvNC3Dyv6k0Ixc6LfHy4024hL3axnGqUm@@6OA6L4rJPKfs0oaTZ@@X71S6N8DX6FDiLemHEIsDZOgWZySNM@rEr4h1XOqjEh76uKI57a3UPnFDV@bxHb55RRU6Ke58glfLohySEuEwOT8269lTyBcCnv4C).

Comment: Nvm, fixed it..

Comment: I had forgotten (suppressed?) that `NegativeLiterals` used such a cheap lexer hack. The documentation could be better...

Answer (score 5):

## 209. Haskell with NumDecimals, 9977 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLfFjF8kiWVKxil1VlEip9eHMeDHr4/GDPZ4djD1rnzPjXew8GNjBYh9seBYLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zzq4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRmRt2oodvfXvw7ihx2a@qijmw5zVNthLUu7Vq0EWx@xF4pmZ9OZQAChqlZn0FMNxy4GgkxmTDOaWgv8zDGvVEO7VS0ITzPWt8yOpfSY01UcptpNpa/azBw4/YHDzPb8ZBnGtnrmpRbHlD3N6ACYo1p9S3UofoWxU0NXeo2WMhWTncqwb0G8zTZV/Uvvi8OaZq@nGC0bIHOMvTEtW0X4pmrbJiZfZWy4pTankOYBVLE0c6@6/3IqqsDYSyii0tfVIVMatmMpTUczDaRJih3vnx4fTqWQZfbuZHt7OjTNXsdNg20PmlfTURl2atmKrkzjX2HVgWPuOtPhWVbtqIbC0olCIj0dmWPrljKTZJVZqtJqa7qagAZhcdZV9b5qMQxhbdNiu1AkPZ/Kp@rVccpEE9Pmx5HTaAtMz2ScqfqkU0B40@qqBpQwNR0pe5FTEWkvoqVRBoo1YmG7a1rARxYb2GqL3ZhWC5jL0EeRGKRnw1vWUGw1t4IIMh6CK8O8MYCJHBOatjFyVGaYRpwSI@AKk/fq04yVzmJo9WB3OjzH0nvTYavAaM2r9mxbpvPsyOyPpkML7I22N4@dMyneETbMFrTGVJzMDhUIomwmCZ9JT/aCJrQudGZ2aUPBWiqzDa3fVx0eCbyiWhQNqZmuGVe8gx9aZmvQxM7ndFXIGzss8oMdaEKqCusLMZFABwsSB3EwKMGx2VP95bWZoUID2X21qbW1Jmcsdeiohg1FthNMg0rcaLrOWqoOCcbYmzFmm9i846CGrnQTzUQAGRNzYb0rnWms2e8zHgW1gCJtp/JMReqxW4jXuzYb9nvM1noQ7TTNdltV2a3a70LyQMsMMPg0@1PV8nxLKsAYqksatQ8CAUljIqWBTi6FbiwFSGvZggaO1gPCak7IZqpiayhQIYmtGi2iat8TtSZTJlieXWvQ4aHqA4tw26pFXY7wQve0VECpeM0cvrE0x6Few6rsUFUsdmKpamRS7E5kCZmZmIODFUlQo66thbYOtkPQuDxFQulDY1qZk7evAgpLlNlSvQTfsiSVAlv7m@xu6QLdXMoCA/StsBJh5R@Ynby4UOE7lBvJjnUfAKwBoIrOkmbfSSrxPhQw7kABkwo60RW/Tif6ui9jtjbVFj6W41AtaA0QPuxdjGrWHFgWjiRjoipXUGndNDpAT6isNTCQHgbLpaAJmiYMBDGmXgPVQPJSG4FcQAqfdDVoNBubxNex@HhIBIUREdhYUNTN1zb1AcFBSttBXgaqQFLEuNtm71hb0XRMAvGIipfaUu2B7mCagdHClofxTm0lmFsM6rAW8PE1ZKcAUgoA1u/5@iUVCoChIUyqKkb9@E//rNXpAJ5qswmyTbDrO9YymzRyK1RYGA4ZMiwIVJ2KBXAxzJ0nhwyuFV1rkYBQjJHIggpBud6YA73FTMjQutGgl3aVa@jZ0LmajsqZnA/2MdZTrrg00TjnQsV7SgMaljKgvKnacfZiA1qpqQaCxDPx3sBp51m8v8VCdvL78PNi@PnihQqFiyQiy0vJZKcEDJdYpiDwhR7jnHfVCUlpO4ptaq1Af@R0TSPN4k0mNctmXzXCoQkcoVjIaoQiCZRy4UhJKzcTbc1ohUNrwIsVyDgUKTXLzXOtWCtNJfdnCWhuEA12VzXcjEgBEDnUKa6TPZDmCRgc3sWFyxdn2nUkOUYnfMFImOmwax4QJGUH@dJEBgE5lLB1Ve2HUwk5gmIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwUatFQ8FQ1F91wgA1nagodtYTzUSxpfe7OGgBUQy7DyOBhbzbhJEaJaOtOaBxxliD@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@6zpO3y7COKE53UEjAZySPLFGu86BgcySdKyR5pjc3dDNBohlG/pn0s0h2Rw0tOFUhSjMa8NLO3ANCljbZmUYuT8PgOvCobYNApPCNxDYFyWR4CYU/FcCQAJKAKHCbZtE8TYIleOR0QxLCepKCeh0UoxJ2HElMHckTOXRZcPsoRRiZ6QYoKYHZp9moK0gZD6JfGXuUOfJftLrQqHEpakZ4bvQ4uJiqBiqgGRfXHwOrjV0PUdXFFzPyRUnF8Il0EUpYuTC2HNKgWG10P25i3kYqWGzDXFUutX6YeW8WMzUYsq5LJ5pfEZA1IFkA@g4PgBPKFIuozMSkSo3UNFEoz1Z@w2UzsdNS@sLIrxSrhXuF1TIEBm0Xh/NSEst4SD7OE16ZQtGQVBam92wFbo4T13ULu4uWtGL@1AMU0dKSrkBlYL8wr1ExzIHMFxGzleKcbkWiZxnYJBslEOp0HI4nI/rkJESiXyXj0QVTu1wSAWpHb64CAFRBX3Om12L8A1j6UjEIxWUAwdm0AnDocRdHvJvRGqRaAjSRkIxMDHKoRBQpolEsKnSyJkTBDo4es0JsxGNBogNTesKvzNiH8ISYGDx5NvAvxvHk2Zv7wqkK2vaOqoicYtrI@BNLvPAFj08javIdkljNWC4hRrAaNvyLCO0xo0B6c@k3Jr@jMgcRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOI29oQDATo9yNXEcLxG3WhDTA4TV1NnJFqIjHoOGj2qom52tAhH1YSTXvMA6D3gLOvK03o2JPoLiR2AQiBz5PJ@TGR0gziaVWJrJqv1REGlqZiIP1aGmntA83uInlBs0JTwmoDVVFlB91AJartsiaM@R2gtDrUHK7DAx8dY5IdxQ5HUGuscq0LlT3UGLBQ7hwADedmE@wdFTQHjOXGI9syrjXLNJDIiS1ADQxfwjaYQj6PvMBG1epuevNh@s5DDhSbCZZ9tPVjnSZu026ypGHqZsdkywCArJlIcMbeNXCqBHQ@B8xLZmu3RKBqxzRGUzyo4nBvo44o5zKe9q0gZJLgE5cga9j8So8BHqjz8e7HLRgh5GwqBeV3fSn6eJX0YZmuIwY22RhATNnqyDfYkh/Vfnc0MaGE/MGtSOAnU@Udk9v1CgyoUCrRw28pqb@T8xDo525Uy3XNq/sWaUg4leG3MiZqD8og9FNRHd5toIbBqWAMdUkxgXSmwcfti4LrIjkhtzzDKd7umY6SfJfo2gx/AqgvxDUm2cnQYigZj@OvRFEsXWHJlnqdRCklMINUPukO1IDa7JpMugDdxQ8kgQjtghIeh0qoFql5XjIxOR1wzAHoiy1V13qas0sTabqBStF4wHdjcT5wjOBQU52AsGTGghsnu8ZS3Ohw@K0hDnV2QKUn2z/Y3KofVk92ylJyYFtJXWtA32ip9R6otLpqS2z6E2RHKiAT6W@v9CPTdMqcEa509tVPENO4yfc263u760fVow@8EITG1noDXcGiFJemADD5MUW7/dU3w9i2zJ6n69uiIZYySHp1YjUBDV8Ru4KxA7GW4AvPYXgP1wcSzUCn2WRxk3u9QAG4ioC4ZkCjYycaRUhaQ/ACBWSeUOI6QsJquIEFDPRWECbm1sfo5sU/nEhgvpNT94jcNgZ231ezO1mm8Gun3UZ9wAtOU/BVHDuRPg7OUDBfgZic@xdkmYmaC@zhWyF8fOViLr6ZqLnAHr4sx4crHvPRTcXMA/WQ5QgZrpDMxTUVMQfQw7RKmPyrKuO4PMU9tKQi8pob/WAiD3eBcOOyyxgVLcKIIBcwzbmjx5dE7DrOvo55JC1PxGIUX0hh8RaYPWsIgvzyBZdYIAj0Q7vfSjhDZ4wi40cRB22GL7B48ZwRZL2u1KFXjkvrhviiWFwHASbnxomzXmJzKqmpjYM9cN6uab0OImDg69JuiD/KS8Sb0F3J8XeKNG9By@yPfH35Ls2J39OEOPH1rgwnN8kh1LusiUhO7b67mjMRx7slX8GpX/JpwLpYwMF24YLwBAb1PRNUsT3NpnVVv2QMeCbDRUBy7Z4JBV8ax6TH848sfj1/4lTyIyKZDWL1ykRze@yqpxJyFrF4KHpX@mzKNmit9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvQabfqZA1AUc3IwLOIiE1LlFa4r4LShCTaEekNgNLtAyIBamqEkj@iB8wzzyjM5YzJRmIbaHoB6nQTzD91fAYsX8gTZbjS0h0CBLlh09zm3kkcDMHHSiZWE7NpTOEMJNhWf7jjZPSBA6L/dmWk2NtEUzsByIJV4/qeftaBJZhusq4zIyPAcdaAkcUv7wfYTSdFDP/PbmmAuB7qmEGHI9TWUTQVXNhTdc8xHjToNi8e7itVDXV40N7Ar/kB/e4TzeMktVR@0VPc5PxMi8eRkHk9taD2qETzRGCXT@4HkU1ORPD2Zc7qptAgLN7o0lRJZ2Pq8XdQhNz982i1IpyeU050xZOMlOqc7cAb8F1flvtauWh@/86lSnGSyVFZpyGrStJWGpj7CB5ZyNWiZ8f5VhyqNRcvNgR3Xv4ETXPG2rlxxZx2d8wnAq2hpnY5quc@HwG66YEeQAZS8occjrOLqWoy0Z@UxnJbOfx8CcffFeI6H6aTp9PMtDEks0oReg6TFpfe4j0zaFGF1pTFCQ7D77ZyFGZISC4Kn3IxGUxkcdb11lvEif7//cHocqil9oTA/NV/05ySZZ8Qk@WJ/nE@CUZ3F8v9Xej2MZVpP0ePpls/5oFh3J1jHrjmgNCsQb@qKDczkiOZQr6H56OcxBsfhqYlsNXY9wt7j4rjLbQ@t3IheKnpy09Q1G7uz/pAYnZ7sHueJ2y7oZ5wUfbOEbZFebHfjnmu@JDCbDi6bPMBoT5BsfMUC14R8nJMwHyJa07zB74PaRte8Vvnv/NHudm6pniCj4jqxhNacK0Bbza9xKi690898Ol7NLZfT1OeGiwWCSdvgqbxsa7ppg5GOv4@RAtRt2@a/87nYTzVNMeI0j@13z08mCtVnCTFv90BbKnrH1HP5TlKBnwcbfGC1UfKL51MlniexZPnrEstVjExDFs8HRf1V0rr6GifQZLeFi2I@5yPj7DyxJRZTHq4gGBS40j2/ctupPKVMJPmMyUMNYDW7N8rIff6E0eQh6rqjSX9EijbofZigkAeHY3Hl@6fktvJ4bq2niaQZtKtfq4Svca90FQYv@p1pUpZOyd@YQk6lni6g2vpAHahz5dNB41LFvY6PmB9PL1RKVGNJzC0mgXg4s@hB3Qoz8kmlxnEbfY8KGEXXoJN/VbuZK@/6oIv30fI@BMchOmYTdoxBf6JxJ8w34@hxynX7bs82WxOFxJhvlUj5r@tQE@q6rdL3IdV@q2eCsWz2QG0wntD@AilNg/DfCcQUMlY0JmZL5mbvrZyDLguqB7SodmXHcaL8aUIn/ZCFT8CFAlhshuqM8PchSs8Tog3T1L@lZUCWtjTa06zHcRfr11poRs0RmyjYeC7DxnmRRvuhWQw@zgjjEqiHhrTziOnsn5t6xBqcmWd/ZLTyzbp/zb6EkZqmiWyr6bofYkiaDZET@cTqo@zItVCzoeoKfwxzK4/hKyQyj@LztA6h3tIqDa7s8LWc8TJbcEr09EdALK0FtklX7ankfUSpV1qXA9t9PAg0NPE7JzqRpJWJB9L1NejrBv5OrBv5tCHHNMCachSro6I5ouNSqQh9SL66Cx5zibvbUzoqP/LwmOgYz0rg7jpuxI2d8@cninzDSxOS8f0Aj7MCdJwrdWS7z7kI34ya0J6D3ten2ab6eBOnQ7/aqRPJues8X1H3jK7ZNbpq16LO4fke6h7AkQ4/rPJYJaD8XcW@wu2EJI/G1lzX9lNXN3X9KdRFecilo2nOn6ndwqMALUj6TXhHSgMixOOrU3gwZBORaOx@qO901QGMTLbpmH01Tr6HQHWc7OG/8yefdw9CNjvTVKvF90LgzJ/iaA1dZTcaFOHS9i9Ez59IauimgjtWH1HegTLu8ylTU03T@uq8R0cxnX6fHvW@PrDph6Z44@35c5dFtk0lfQozaA7fhsJZVu2YjWZX@1qRGqriGNpV0p3D4d5H7VIhjKnmGotvYnBC14BW1iiBTFD2xx/jY/eh8c@3pjO39hsDyxp9XTBMbgHwplr5kgE6HspfrNbOiaYhH/dZufuJHlm3EIu7D3ITKdCoLMfVFGgl8oMzQBNbyoT0olXGB5SeqXpTYXwLa98ydSl2B9Aknubb4QDh8yYvHhKEO0K@gVUY3hl07MjXGbfbAp0Kf@YirHbw9BZfWrJ188Y30QxdXzHEY@6o7C1DPrYmkn10USSRFIufcXXw4OyWrvVt/svi7fRcLLOr@bNQo/mWrmieltrmyxTo@ppm1zMt3FcPKkS8aal2E2e8UfpyqchFjmF2QArHdTYGdmHnVmF2A8E83WRyhIu/31c7Cu6z29Nwy51uzw56gHl6L8FTEL8dKLb2dmA66lyc03sKnoLyjdLRmjsTreAidKkrNmXxx0QnwKDZhrjpajZtb3Yd8zsOZzNanp@NnJ5U947ZPT4R4tOLxC5TFt9l7m5Uz4HT@hivzM1rUusUK/MPCjrNoQlT8Zxbz/n7Lx6bRbgZ9PoDWzzm597Dwwr@mePeFYXbNxpIwfhnELqsq@jO/Nll3@Qp6FNiJBw7H9KyP2q62WEf8ykG6hcIOFS6H2CsdRiXDxUHeoAxh1kp/yeuW@LcRJwrNfZnYAQ1w@KaoTmPz8M4jgJ2kPvECnFVCw/jJPfwN/HiWzHET@ZTZe9RiQ9D@qipg2XzNajDD1@BUDe@PrR8ZdkFhkrTGDhxPMD42BCRe3SIKLJhPufjARZ@u/XmNOKyQqfb5Jsbv6KJ2SpYdANbH41dD67@z@EwDQ9uPyxkZ1O4psGm2lYGunOEK3pPSVft93Wc2QCZvmnOM2EORzDEfJMdBKPEoLepNnElcLYMfCfOER0y9Y4j2TGxixbCNEuchbQT7oHjIO04psNJ7mEVFsQjUwPUchzTSjCCC4eVaDQSCfBEuFLUMQDMhaIjn3gcjJ8mtRkwk0OwWpudn7Olu2ExVZTvWZlJRYnVahwrfuhw0tawT@c1j3jy8yWlVl4KxeOhpdCFUWSpkAeu6iAv54IrE7BtjR68vGMSMEPh@8rR7da4xI@72V06Sgq2QQtsjFODpv7QXuGHtviJwBPcm/I3f9kSJ2w7KlS2p4HOAgTBA@ZmT@2aN895viJ34AQFT@giDhjedH5eLL5RZSB3wRjhB2vNG3a6fZIXx/XEaXbwHHJl1SsFb1ycDsPN9g5vPF4ab@O0yNhL5VYKevmgZ4D513K6doIda7SPfmCNt62CC8EMx0IbuBVju6yl4g4AOh5B0z66aV7ROScsyd/8JT@kSIckxOZ1N3s6nOzLEc9CyHQysNk0B1BqF8mtapkCJIxEhsFugBOqDOUfhUfw6ACdngSOjLtnBykbfoBwo3rM4lsshAf18UhSSWuHl6pHL9@dp2rlH1gvqf6nnyUjd4Jw0nfxQs6WYswFKd0jY/mjsxA9jg0xaWko8Qy9EySa6L03vD2ARApnMjxE4vKYafZFr6Hz33Tc2eNGcQ9JGN3Uzu4hwh4dHSeGVW/oECHtrzZQCcAz2YYNHQy8EULNe115KTzg837xY4dlIUM8iKmAix82pzMVeCAOkywN2RfWRSaLN3GfP/g4IXU8g9krr7ubxDL@rXzJTbUxoN0q1@lEOlOm6izVy2sVcllqy8Sz0OffXwzTqfjFcHWrlrRdol5cDL9Lpd8D1U0LUj1LYs/b2t@8W0pUUl@@2MqISdJ9qMS3HoKYWLo73D3cOj6pnpweQyvcu@Jn27R6yljWIBfRzv2uqdMpc6CLpan2N8gfzwfg4TBbUtga3p8SiQT8W8cJVNBaiktL3OkTTROpv5J8Xnpb9cXPAgiZ1taYy1G7MGpgGwKzIdWw8oM@npVnIq0470tcpqGMxw7kEQY3eM6RpUQqiZWBWHEg1hNJxR6u7HMe9hSKfRXL42R7PhcEKebld@7F8yrOJcH9b6XefRgof/N6cyyP15tgHqk3gHqhbprt6u7e6dHWZDLgMXqS1C0XsuLMBBfO2NP4lKF7wJkOromEOGdalphECbhXDGZ0OU5DdW5UqJYQjs0eT0wcSuWXAmPGBMqU8YahWonTIhymEqAOUsJqTR3paGtDXxHdMdqH7o5X0RMC25KH2i14QhKYg3TbSwI/bjUQqyCX2/UOSYgLeR2y/epPzO1xWDUco8Eco1QPDFXeqGMz@PeNSq4rXWNDJoYzucbiLA1fXTU6UGEXNlLiYxRb4oSQlnjZJa@8eNMIlKl1qdDUBW0mFKdWYJTWlT5eayCg901HLbLPA5MO37nCxNMvbtAwVvilOtS0TQVrQ4f6DAevKHDHLcK3u31cRu2Mq2Yk3/08NzBwoAIg3xU3oHVbeBtRm2Q9vyyDk9wU9zK4QyXNZdviHLanJdjsWrNprhsboY06jg6SEmsjKo73S9GxS1bVbdBJWjB889uYSDlJ0BZ4vg8@bjApCDyZ8FTGGJMCCGuXZ8/pw1B604Rh9RNPvERwhNn24QytLcbjQLmOZrj3IRVxSp7mKovMsQa4caQSmkniFqFIrnjX6ek@wDk3llyoyR//6Z/xW0ouHHD/XLiHqXXw/aHwtcH9T9wYWQbfP/N8afD9Efd9n8Qmm72aQWQvLLUHzwsAX76QZuqEMsG9FIrq4rU2tvS73UNm07oBtmVPGfqaCSUM8pxmAL20HjDFNbUxgvMcxk04xhM@fwcsAnwF/IHqDWo0lJ9q1cJ4QL@YTGLBcXIjQZvM1SFfNKDz@p8HeE8NKGHJXDa3IiehkPFrFyEdmu3grmaOMBIpgkwMXGv98qdGE0@vMMluKrpazpU4bySXlO8z0ievoEsAG@CGwjmDNHjgxUsBcRWRLLykROUIJsWBLCSHUKa1TM5qoA2GyQEgEQw23LOBoG6aglTAx4Y6dEhjGrkGUAPvI8PJTpXfVuQiigMijhtvU5nujuN9ynjQw9dBE/5mkM4Q7BjBitI8Zj3/nl04F0ZN3KrDgPF@OYd1DXD/4zlX7XDOwmPEs3e8hKdvaMHasBfHhon72behtCycTqYzSTkX8XGoJFBBebGrfwGU0LlBWDRV7dLs29WNrd1XB4fHM3eVEGRoGizEQpW16EU8ETuveY6QV@5Joq5vJ4/frG@7pPSXarzlAyHG@z6mizkvt@mSPpD7Gd8gPps3RcxkJKeeipgWWePbtC1qFvs4NukD3OD7U2dyDUfu7s9ra5ULIziT/Zd59zcFE8vIXOC6sOn2ptB0MbGIu@629xO8F9JOuAei0tL4djLvGBf3j4Mfvm3Eu2VyfOWIu8E@QEd2x8d6Ew9svYe6J5I8K7pvgxfMLS/IGreoMhZ1nGEzMLNtx18aJuoyeyGmOJPmEemAzyG51xnaHNIm4cxnmejeH49mHtyJixG7/vgSEHH7RRdKp2uNwI04qO2e6PMOaSfsvq454UjAEBDTZ/tmIe1H79LwwJTy@ZB5h9Rs1BmHCZr0DdNVVTe1AL@KhLk3hkTp0pHDAdDt0Oyz8Szapuq6jkCnYpsDPgmosleDHsC16XGk4mihgpYVh8RAz5BblHO8ZkNQItFrZcPDSKKrDltaB0accCQGouk7WR5fV6LgfRugVzXm1QCnpfpdBeqATZNZw9s@hpG1AnnHFeTTj@xmfrBRCwAyTNqIFPnMRejUcG@WwoYvslDMo0wjEgslGLekxKVRtPWAJqISbKOLGzVp6qPd1khl818CwAfztmb1ElgrGGY4C73Ebdp@rvmmm2N8lFHOlYRmtNRhGA/pF2tIJwgP3ZxdhyLSDIvT9TXispLW9D02rixUHCGUxnfATMm7QsGTc5OioVDAg/543BGMEsjx2LH2wAkqQrjdU/osPKCLgGyWYOQNX4SNmO1YERav4HB9wwwWjdKcBjwoAmwWBG2TS6MbF8J4b144WYZGwlDbaOHjVuuzczmRqIGbMomwJZzP3ABtCmcCIwGwUSFJkdCCfgF/RSwRv@U0IW47XaJsA3QXB0DNjSY5hfP7IF@AFlRrVnnmu8NgLGA4VQuFomiNSWlfYMAXa3MEIqCdI8VdGwHoK46nAdVQRgPUhqW2NJCXL16rhqECgYBnenipqzIAJrMiMfe@4dj4PkDKIciLuCPOu0FBJ@8J3Ard6Saoa0vJEk2Nle5Brfl0gXpNW2g2o@R/m0wkS3fhJb08SoKuGamEl7plOZpZjkaXjOXwkoHa1rNnOKN2vwTKXD0BBuoQgOJLeqQE/AzKX3nJKC0pa@GlVjm9TCnACybyHST4wU4m7paU@@TSM1CWYhBicaETXrLpCp9UIiHfQ/mwhywlY8Azd3gXDd0ijNkvadEoliGxVMcC/JC8OI7SsHlxnKTJu5KwBZKdnuhuU6qY1xIztx9zAorgojdgZXHAEnsX6y7w@JbAzLy4B9Q/nvFr3OHNaGOKavuNL2ky5umCRchplLlCyIT5HUpAwGEYiIjemBKJgDD59a@Dco4x6XkuEzajz7OpUjSUlcFMB/s6@AL08OSyZEl3F5vxa6a207nP8XOlnfhcO7w6PHwfuQizAgsFNw4keUX6Hi96ftpnlaUf@LCf/gkGl5OBYHJZfraaTH769AksDvicVxIVEB/8EzmPh2rn4VXGKqury7Fcfjn2IlT3FSsSTqcjx0zTkuxC69utFnzNLl35HQ7yz/PnlBeY//DPeJjIXzhcD4KI0OA3wl0r2SC7WFWU5ehK@oVRSqRT6b/5d4v3sbvD@trf/F4vqS7i4wAfP79/g@5jOfvd4uJ36@srKzEgJHcffjz8UK1WVzZj2cPz7POVeGpx7T/@H4uL6fRaOrlYs225Fjq/ei@lUytS4m/@InR4@LZu20CIAn4yTAYn/ubhK7Nsll2xW/hctRn@k/u25XMr6G60b/HeJLBXyiRsQqFsJnT8fWh@sy0yufJ89T//8cHnoBOspJNnFjyd4OdgLh/kTnCAL@P6roOV4BqC5e6Do2S5XAbn6n/@XyF95RXgwZjRGvxUsi6u3ChYiZcpyZdgJQcOOZ2GfP@vn/0sEKwMg7dBWZaDI/qroxs@@WfyM4aOpLSal0zzBV5Kjp@h7zOuRVKW0xdue/qaG5vWC@4CbmhXZvrCvHb3uIoJbiDHU@Eq8LOFn7/93//2T//2j@nvT@n7H/Cu69zii0@bjKkwAuOnWHwx0w57U/6jRBw@Ca93BNEbFzUL5suxOi@Vx8JBn2OKDt4vEyTx/N8IFwi6F7aiHKpNNMZFUM6vHLwYPvnDxoV2aRsck9TLnE2HuY3heZgrC9i3wAWCP5TLRw7@vWng36GNf2z4Uz7IDs/hswh/9A8fz4u/ixQigglk9rP4G0jfQPA8eF6r7Rj497lLfxb@NT7j394t/n128O@kiX9Hn/Hv5Bb/2ExtAsG1tbVgNHoEKqNg2qd8TuGbSNSFz2PeYCD4W/2wlYPcwYsA9IlaNH5/f574fhgtlcQ/KFMlz4cf7oJi1e7j8bXvK9HoORXvvCLKuRavVaCsvMj08/0aII6una@tJeqVSiVe@75yvjaZSKR78SKKHfUFJKzUzs8DwTtsizL@LONP08bftCQlyfsF5ToM1IVAEHXcAld1CyKA0dsa0B8Iflr7FI4@jz5P6anrlHwlX70xD8b/BwdDiNCGqUvTSnVTXbkFopKl1NPUKDUapnrmgdwCpwp/qR44tVR7mOqkjJQhy6PhBKqH/3sHpvPmwARsJqR0hikHEafa8OwcHLwBfG3I@xL@tFQqNYRCDlPX8J/SUXDTRXD0/L4euQicM@mTCmpBQg4lUqFELhTSatlc/7MUC9UvzkO1UjBpX1wkucLE0islugDw/r5e39rfrNeTyEJrS9EX0fgL@JQr0TXxeB6slJ5fFOPYdJz1EvVgcu35RSUTR3cuCu2ThrC1ZPQbP2OU8KwsXgTABjw7w@/ZzfUNd5GDXBdnZ14s/iQxiFwUBB8ATc5NP@FgoHz@jv5bB/9l/b85ZeHzWoSx8N39Wpg@EfyLRO7u7@7FbyUSDgtPeA3@MAD8mOTuvoJOAroD13k4Uovc3/Mw@A1H1jjCCuaxVqHEY0Doq0Ge60WoxBgYS2GxznZxMUylIqUGhHgz7soXWrKJlGgzy1IDl9nAQJCXIwSSXSmVVoR7NV8q5YVbzuVKpWUPKgUe4QQg1VaaJWT0UrAfwTJw9g@ncJ6FblkNhVtqG6/bf97vg7EnF1JfvnhB9XpLs@p1DM98@XIBPSmEe1nKhSyEpPJfvkD3C0XAENw3xSpqAcw6OZkeo@8qtuI4VhhM/dhFCPe82RehCManUykExvQsu7aWW6lUcivgzuUjkZK0xDfChDvRghy5X0pKvBpgooWCIkrOr0Yo9D6E8Sy4xp5XgMNt/LC7@yBRm61kI@HGSI14AXKhwEPYSi6cjxbEX3kxwtaSlWUm/s7PM9GV5dXlF7XaeOhCMVG6U8ryfflOKeK8wX2pKe44xS2myrNnmQLQJZ8qXQTq9c3qSbWOL4vANWmQvgwDSeAEcL2xb4XOaZInW6idY01qF6FQsfSCN2w@y4KhkoCLh0B0sXyBKhwES1Jr497yIWHl36K8nM4sJrPD73JbKdC8vyzj5/z8PJ/OR5dBtC0XCrVajUK/LFKa896wXaO7rsrxczmXrcVRd7kctpeDfSavZoLLgT7tLlpNsRYu0Fo4abYIgdCurIFr6baq6@61sjempbdutJYK2A/3qhtbJ7H0GqBMb1c3Yunj0/WgjN7s2E/RGfQfbVU3D04hweHeVvV46@Xuu63TQwi3YYAEYsGnd6ioA7Wu3gwGN@ivq/TZ0Gzl8lLp9@t9@AzbP/7yD3785X/345//0Y9//gc//vmf/uoXf/oH8P1L@P4Rf/7Rvy1k8fdXv/hn//OP//rPIfA/wPffw/ff/eoX/@Jn/Ev@v4bv/@kL@2vx9cHxL5ASsP3hr37xx3/xq1/8k38J338lvv9y@vvjn/xv/P8/ij90/vmPf/LX@CM8f/BHP/7@H//4@7/34@///Mff/4eA/O//6pf4/8d/9ff//pf4/7/8m7//q//h7//wfyLHn3HH//2v/i3//bvf@4O/@/1//ne/94sHfv/g0d9fPCH8F7@DkKeX8yl4nlKvbw35xU8qz29CjXEuxGB/@o9//Bf/CDj3T7jvvwcf/HtRP/c8XkyUrLp4dBz4c8a@JEFvSr344oECyv8RQyGYfZnERqEpN/RXv/jnf4HBE7D/yI8hJc/CLiGwl9vPAfZfewXzw/78x1/@7Me/@Ic//vLPfvzlH6JAi68UYtVYXP7KxBAAZp8Ah4C5p8ABoLyGa@SLbDGQBsfiGk5kBOTop09A0kVwgQK@HMhmwIeGzPSnVqvg5@I8WblIXlT4pwb@RLKCIYnkRRLjE0lU6eUKIYNSRQOQMxhEy3wmIooTEPAdBlYK4MO5iSgMQVEeFYWo9Sgrl8vRwLAMcQQKXkwzZJU8Wl1odJQBLybiaWL1PGi1bLhOWCBlOXrE6svlIU8YxYAKYWBYIAw6kuS0FM2XNyHD8nCTIS5EHg18guenciVfHlYQ3Q9UBMARXYcsAaqMpRtWfgB/mXACfGC4@QMUJV@ORit5CClTVSm3WJ3ylLNUOap7lFG9MRwsYHg8f8HYd5Kcl7jxB23BBDT@RsfQz2kO5DnEX0SXRXXo33XSdxnTQ0MPiT48jMc/x2BKLwAAbzyOG7LgG49jaV5A9JCjilK28IhyDEC5qJhD8gJomI4GotS@UfJA/lCGp33WKj4PosPqLC0tgWutImWkAzAlmHVVtB3FwvUKUpKKTMoVJAzG/S3q0iEZG8uby/Arw//WIu1R5eRYDiyFUBcIMTePeDRjrphBKr1bNarLMpU8SnCB4DicK7i06ASa6QqLBMJ00XqEjFW134fnG7uzbg5BCY1JUkzO8WnliLBlP5jFYvkHeWU1AE/yD/COd3HbODQDvvcrgb0MCVq5i1OPQyfoK7lApSIWzpgcqBxvnUCCkwMmp1MJBprr3cpqeiW7kk1ncrnsalpeyRVWctl8BkRcLpVNp@XCykohX1i9pyK9AFERKy43smuVfzDz@W/@wbzP/FD8BCrv2TDB4veByjAeT6apxGU5u1oalaEcFBSokCbGdfTRXRz3SwYuaH/WHW4FgmIF7uLIpgvwYYGFAFuAIPgAWlwyYGIde/egJBb08O0ZfFFPkrPACJHABTACxxboT3wC2GrPQNQ8k7kzmxs7U@g8waNb@5ABtIHB9nDnpGOyE5Pv0FtXm4E1ceioEgjQ8sc5ULQWwLvpz2uBtaQXOx/TRpe/UW7DMkHB/ekw64pxxaM2Nbwpsul4UTsK3gdl9zSn@wDEab@HB2FU63eGYavXgALiNCcHWIcfSzfNeQCr7PTwgVq@8Y6C4joinQUF8KPdlzsnvufJVnVjJ5Bj6wf7m1OPrADKsr2t7RPPu8pj3aRZD8WHrb29aa94oJGyyLKrsRgIR/jBZ4w@9Ewsfe@CyImHh91UDKyounrM36hg2tBbZWDqslwKsqV0tiAXMoXV8nr0qD7IS88XpQxYoU2FdQrZVWD6U2MwbKfzIHnwPUSpYi61P@gNLEdbAcvpPe73DbzBDWUFmR@M0OzADlg2PbxxHi8ncAKW2gIr58agMx8NfG/UoM8eDIQHBqHT0jpdyPfGdAECDUVh8P3WD6RX/R/n8QCH50FhMzH6HHBcQtPaLBVI0CxYupDP5guZdD6WL@RXsmAAZmNyOiav5lcLqZickvNyLg90j@VXCpkVkI0Qmy2sBoIgQ7R2MgmiX5YkempGE2@FXcPrdc1EtxII8kkEGG/xhYhBxQsY5JmUyV@kIJ0UwM2yTCsvSvjK0RS@0BMQKqzJgtvbG6ntbUlaRw/O9W2kJKmFnmw@lVpdlySVYjZAfKclyeRpIArAHO5JpdY3JGnAEeA5Vknqomcrh4qqJGno2ahub2M@l@hJY3oAu@Ix3KO7nlUAM9CTyZCmK0mfPXQAV@UZrVBJt9CDeWLMNo/ZgDhJeumWJ5UCDEccjmPYcetarUrSLvdUqxjziiqe5UV9jZ4qfSTJAg/woCR1wNGxwCSXpAY4kRMlqQmu5kiBsB648Mij4SiSNOIEQhJJ0pCgleaVBEqVCMdsdnZ2lK7TUjv8M7L4swlFgxhtONjabrx82eh0GtaouvXyCGNevdpRLkcDq9FpiGSNOnxMSAMxV73R9AfKuFuvK/rcmNcQY0zF1Ed1FctWVz5DmcSng5n06q8g5hXEzFtC4djg0wPQBn7We/BcVxoU434ohp7DRkMqIY86o76Kcy3YZWjTUckf0lOalllCF2jhbDEUDsVG53ItdluiGNZjLBy5S5XuEaQdpreJoJQEledudD4sp2qge8slnAYKL/aeS3IhKxUXlefhIbpzUhG07xUpUsQ3sZjtEAvF5ecg/nKrUnEZntJzKQPOYTgVSjEGP5Hz1dpzaRWRSM@fxyUoC3gBRIGE0moBERZWQRMo3QM9HJC1jYGj1uvh8I2qXEUivE787U3s7Owscsc3WmlUR6fUDg9jwzIvDdMipVso/DSmlgpD3qDpmBbH1wEK3D5PFamSkH1egtxZMhlZQ4GEIgSen2geO8GKcf7eEjmfiyRwW3bdbNfpDQLskzvZfXY245r1g4p4hqcr6GSluw2HtGO7GDhBPZJei8jw6HgD3yREZ1/BQOF3WNB7f1TQKguBQEUoVifq0EnsqLglplkSYRv8pGLCd9gWiPJR6@M99CU6VItHHN@YhtJiIpjdUPb1SqVcL9@e1@JxLO7aWnANsnJTwPDF1gUkHpFwd4nXy@tQqlTJwOsaVPQuDYPDQKWlOApYaOt3g2IRYO9LnfI5Jv6CP2txqSJBPudfaqCBQpuNgkrZHjToWD9LNUBFzpWGECavrpSuyiyezZR0ppT5EY8l2uillPxlC0dKlKp8nk4VYjBcwDACXviu1hYXw3rYMbcMqEKqWMSaKOUKeeGpRKLpZT3cMpmyFr8FBgXux531LBLVw7IqR6JXkRILL0bKtvqZK8VfdJwGXayXU1w9XrIHvfPUYk6O3cXr8XtdsZ0leTVdPB8sncdlyD/1pbMmfYQqQ53vA6BJ@2dpYYArQZjLeXxIHA9q47B@CfQWXQUKyYV0SYAE@oL9wxIL4/us@NajcCi0mg6FIqESQC1CMPWiyB0xfQi6YugZdEAYVKEHFtIQb6nOAPQ5EA0zJeAmQE4OBO8DLc3us5VCIHgXuL@7X6u46tJrNhop0bjrfcZYJwrGYJJWlXA9apFc8UTlBauWq52jakmAVjfIZEsG2AU/0BZPLn7r2lV0rfI9f17gkiVkE@DEoZXd5Fq0QlMcAUmSgpK78BDOZ8HOw9mUH4J0hyTbuGsPDLpXovgGyaUUufZ3Xov8sK/pd/lMvEKWBHDb/X0wupbE5dBEJUnEah7QboFA0DCFE6ehHeikIGWyWQmNSpX1jwvfr36f//7N6cHpwTZ7kSrmi3lOiQtu58XkkBwCyr4A9UY72goE@1/MrPyD8aoULPZDmZVQZkJRvSiL49xh5IPwOa7UwLd2DuZiLQKucll@Lq8WNVsspISL9qCvWpHnci5dTKfkSNCu4FnT9GoQiIQuObcarAU50pXVCLhpDSAtBytJESyvYro49wELZ4N24UswncoHgvk3n74w5r6GV0uTK5kUxV26X7uH/8r9ORjK92Qv39M//iTh554D0D8mcD30GH8m4MYw4/jaD/E1/r9GPxsHvORSDpoi@Ak6vm1/X/@@HgwEC6FKNBnCV8rzz1AYoaimLhv0p9rL@Pf9OGDZtu1lzwfeZagzy1ZkBoptMnkReZsGlbZQyOVzwcCvZz/JZbCYlxeqLMQvauJDAl7T6J1oCk28GAsnOZYX4pvHBxuvt05wTFANfLEp2zjYT2AUvntzfCStqauKpY/EyzdHCIVDycnGITMtdrp5SGnO6DAihdJchshlabdVFG@oiV0zOZHBBbJsMrWSlLNMzhdTq8V0jikgjGy8fEC4ljApo2ptmP0RN0TCGxFKvFBFGIzb08A8tNUie3m4RynoXoLlhc2tNwfsYH/vQ8IN5eEnO7vH7Phg@@SserQF9Xizdcyk6jHbPZbY2e7JzsHpCavuf2AQfVTdP9ndOkYEyQAKMlSMOME8q4Ct2SM7iVqTTabBRLBtNq9UZzJcsfpKEu8dnQw28LUkKt7dPxk@MGBMbfmtjuPqAldBGKJXWi0rgKcgtSZbQJNjYVm1cKuw1E3Zqyw7eH@bsrKLrLmyH1plzdS@kVlbZXpK/DF9pZc5YouLixeG5I0C/mp4Ro8/CPfPQ9i4TLsftxbCuRW2DKZOeiUyjtk/OFxIub6Fs6OTBdmLO9pcSHue3e2FjOfZAt@K59s@21zIer716uuF3DjZ/sbCqufb3NpYyHs@YNKFwhjn/uaCnAq4xLo2tdYCvXotvL27t8WWAShSmojFGSZ0TAUDIcIDw@ZXUpCVt7x80zVjpDM3RlPQLfVr0C74BNQCqjznSNdajC2bffjpqT0AhmQBT4lVrE4zJrDiHT0wtgTuAgtYoQWsEMAv4GFohGOLZZaOMIheaPO1@jC/sy3GpFObjjx@Z7M1VEcrwAwxuvSHjr5CClW8gzGwcC9Qhts0C9em/bwECpYBkywpEsHzcvune3s8MxgdLNMKSwTJyCPNwWn2ARtUEX6x6hDKG4c3C7UF0mpBqBb4nsjA/URrBqZbE0kB9VxYaAKCSepeK3qMoWoVwzVgxIsevg8fgCEa3Clw8YOC4XAT69pRnSYVKILE3DrY5jXEVeQym2zlCMNMiVIUzXf4f/nCXN@FM@m1Jr1GiOMWyHmxOD5e0jLCRjBswT2hSRB0Gp1SLiDHRKOQGqpDcb56LQDR4csPr7ulrEBGqRB79ozKsQa@QoiywHRRypHFEQQRCIIR@RCZV7RFKm5kIbmMmzz4S9aRiDiO8GtAGyPv4g2QrNMFnWpVrxd6zblggBFWmhLIIqrdwrYGdyZdBz@KR@DkGGtAN4kxN1LOYSTaODGmxlgbgqdkal0zgHNVaywTXVaAzkitv7/JW4jfMkPhPIBqDHKvSA0GwuIZdl9i9IWFhgWmaMmFAnlIUMC3yDRhJASHezzd0SYlW@b9BdkSUz8l5e520eUjnhrYQXAakRUvBuC8IqpLgZUx0Ax@gQz7bxnQc5bkyKJRAeFxmQDbmoSLxzncvcuXX6nE1nQtFr@5FiiWH6zF1hOr8ZvVAoa1MYtALUDEhwFvFKDpZ7I10/NQwFhIKKg2Pw0FDKBjXoI@PoHgCelhyB2nj397ehiki9NdGfottCCXCjzJpLc56W1NerH7QojCwCZIr7AvrIEuOQcuPCDO8uBocVk5mbA96aUpkDJT3TRtTwLzHIDnUFRyMGTAWWGMEiRh4ysLlB6@OKfMqtv13f2tk8lYxJew66LgXXxBPeURmQQTBcJ4O4yeiFeicBuJwPXN8CHPI0b0rB@fHG1V38SgfBG2Nu4B0zoA/IieMFGDezcHCDXUJozHrRgLH1fZcoQ9w5LFmJgxQM@Ts9BNWwVUD@bYGvTTlFWKg3j@yZ4UxB4ZmJOVFGbhCPtycQFDamqVyb3@l0wvY6xmWmyUWUVll@PxdBAh5V0Bs8@7Jlc2ELLF76crzs3sMpViK1aGOWoXNO5hyprFT/W6x7GNhkX3GGvfJKPMLjE8NYyyRVz6AePipGrzuBZJYyPyAYZiN4YwHM5p4ixK@jmyJ8W6ChYvS0v91rJ8TaOdLEucl2WNMp0tw6/FVCOYS4Gpo8p0d4rZd/oKnuYVkQd9nFE5xCArEOAzLb4rtMImvqzEiRTp6hOUKfU6XkxZr4dtVW/ji9IHVhOGfFSXbQGGH4xN8EjqSOiYjBTkQf1pMqKl4elbvD8URp0phPS@9jJd2BemHAMBr2S2o/apVL5i4GQZvtbXnyEY2BN@aFY8FecrcaQotOJtBfuDi@x84tYjjmNgd2NzgkE8z4Z6bDonzmObOXF4ud28JO5p7Tlxl4PevBKAYHggRpy3nBNjmAfzEvBLg8YRtXMfAc/9BK7VwpH5TQ/9arLFfbc@Ef1PrIEqrjDaPfCxICiXggN9bR3cVIFpmxpeAT@NyDvxDSnDw4jv8LnHVpExJyl2U9Om0buYBCI6PUm3nLNhsdkFrN/J6Xwk5kPow9ji12A@hJP5kEIJ5yAJsmPifXcO1PZQIwtO4x2nT@DdCUYLzLtxArP/CDzGjmGx8V3gBbz2yovxmHlOlxujK84yDoXjzDs2vzxxQdhD0G4l5IifoL9p9vFvzT7uyx/75E/KuszOJ8tRi/r8RQgY19Ht4D8pI7fUk7lFvqnGfq5R1asH2BcvcvFlwy9wmMzWQyMkkMdTblUIPQY8UUggLj@ib5Av1HziePm81OPxZ7nM4rKXhku8cW@gyXVf4QN49US9jne21ut0WV@9jjNL9brEc6CBFwc8/6ArOhuPS4CWWjcpNizFFSkmxePV443d3bhmSDF@q3ZZsh3TUut455YUw/XTskQCq44wXVXvlyWxsU2xGaWWHs6j6ssDKvj1TAiI57JrUCbjy1i/nl3TXyXzCVUypzIbXxD5hNyOKDc8C/9YTha/ac3NaIMuA8Pb1SxVQ0HD7wsX78TGWzMmLmvAKX1RBJ6vTTN9Nl6RwYtEjzqGibbGuyZoabfMaLZPci@PkWbuehG9Had6EMGYUzn3SYf0ViFGF4m1VKFn0fRQQhpfIikKlhA19fG7q6DxuzfGA9rkhTKivDF3btLGacypoo4Fi9nHyp9LeN8MNMCh2Ydf784ZcHu3zoAb753BIFfUgRsvncEUbeEQ98@Ai26ggSewtzS@8LKnDLXeACdu/LcaCE1uXCwc8rEmNOpT5KT04xRFiISONweHBd5IVCpKUHWbbruZvvEG4eddehOpBWaFLF3RjMX0qQ7zkM69RicS@y00kk8RQ9Fsi9JA2pjEJK6EUFq5WAPj08c7rohB9XkqzOSznogIahLz0o/HK9@lOeUJ8wIpAsYDL8w4AZ9l8r@9j5T7SNFTQcYt5ofiituccuPW1AcL7sfgKmqRwCOW1P9v7CR/k/wXair9f28UzZg@v2NT5hET5putld@iWfBfFfr/qtD/BIX@t6bNP6CST6Oc7fFT6vpX1fBvV79I5o1g2LA61zj1lv4pethvSRFY/SY9wC31ufyYLvD18dlFk/YP6z9xlA78OnnSyp1tm9Vq9aQnW0cvq51qt3qE9xOtp/aiZ5cr65s36y/XW9XNzc6rzsa@@jZfXdnrv36f//CyfftZBe195@DVx1u93@wG3h/1b87Uw5uMmrerg8Hn3Z2Rs7N@2ts4zn5YvUlt6dn2uvp5U7c335y8f33yMnscvfn86vDVbS/Vsw/bKaXQy@y8yb3bGJ0Zgey1dtra3tMOesetrdN0b29T@7Ad3UjtHRfeyqm9rZuPmY2baDaV3O2/Pnh5dHrZ2PqoH@3ufWhtfDaV3Oerm/5uslVob1wevQscZN7KO58PDjpb6cLLneTNZrvfSqV3dCt7@f7ocP30w073tbLV286eFt5fjg5z3bdvr539aGflLDd4Y69Ejerbt@nXxsvr662jQEMxT6yMema@lfs3N4dmobeqvt7f6fTeWrKRPMi@ix73Tm42t9b1z6vDzOmHs7c3K8cfBm/evvp4kNKOjxtbSq7faKWPL09WAs1eZjd6fbp1mldets7e9q53d7IfNpNvuup@tXWoX73s7Hw0jw/3dqsZe2DIexvX@oeX3cs3V5sbu7p5eKUb1ZVkVj9pfTg4CJy@0hqb6s57@1X1svshmV2/WvkQbfVfnlzedq9erR@fHuTTw8NRytywjxo77eHmUS6dTzb1z0e3bfONfPo2mru@fJXWPlRvnUDmdpQt7Okf1J7xKtrsfBx@1pPRU1ne@Lh7@@HD8c611agap5/fbR9dWm9axoF9kDp69fpNQ7/KO5f9j8bxsdxMvVSv3kRTSmB4umNDG6knSnb1pLf3tj/cND8f7X60c7fR67OrjLp5dfSu@vko1bgx@u8Na0/rbaRaB0r1nelsDYYvm4Xr06sdfe/zgf0h8GZLzma3zba93n63UniffBltX718vy4fD1P7xlF7JWftv3t7pmlb3fent0fN7Pa7fr7nGJ23t6e9rejW3rB7q@ZTDf34w5UROM0eHx2mb4zXWs/Z3jl6k3MOUnvvDls7I7n6VpVvjNWNUXZzaOUyZ5vvrQ9XO0Y/@UH7PDhMqdfR1oe@s/JWa7Sb77Rm73Xg@FX3dP/w3c1uNme97Bna@mE@tb@3s7Hfaa28Hu2@GWztNS5bL3ffq@/7J7mr9Nb6WW7z/XHGObl67RSa173MYT56oveczmk08GrQHawenlmf3w0/rlR7DTVzpH8wR6tyb@NVPz18V906uO1cHfbNfXk7PUqe7plXeur25OZ2x85VR9H88NTpmc6JPMzKbwOZm9u@86r/6u3xwfqrg4@vlBVNO1Muj9@1UpnTfFLrWpndXO6lvLXd7n3uFVT5dvNNRsn0ulF77yrZ2midvju70i97r3uXzUC@YDfXdz8OFHOrkZZTH9bbW1l1b33vRFZPO6@PVzb3U4fvW4enn4cnrY33g9N3B1pq6/JVYa@z8v7oXeH16scT@0Q5M9@/tvYDw3zGtOVcIXuTOS7kD7rWcebssuB8fH2ZW9fPGvKr3XRP3das9/lR/qp/273p3ByrqUbn5eZn5ai9BZL09DClZAdX@8PjQObdSe96tb8e/XDVfP3ekPX8mbaaPPl8Wbjqdl/fbDZXzqq3n5Xsy0u1cLydbOjb2ZfRo423h5edzbPb/Eortb73Tnk/3Oo6HwJvd7TNy8LZ1cFwJL/dPh71qilDz14fn2WvT8z147Od43z3TcNqN3YuuyAbeqPTy5vB9Y662h3e5F93L98pqb33@Q3DXjlMBV6pu73W0cnr99VoO60WnOuDD/v9s/zZMPsmb54VzIO89rrafjl8e9DeSq32tbOT4elWN7m@ofXyIFMO9VNr4@DtzsezV/1UIG3k1m83zOzq5@j18EPuLHkY3Rt8aJ6ke2eWtfNes7bfXx@@f31c3Y3uNkYvD6@Ugw9b2eP9jQ37VXRby6mjncyNXd3I6G0zYPfWh/tDq1/IfLza68BIYLYKrZcnmTPDrlbbN7v5461q9aXd2H2lDIcv26swRuBn6@ydWQ78mt89F@DXzvGHwu@5CPTsTsMcgrzkR@UCdO4pQOeeAvykE@2T5nuQf51cDpz4N/3Tu2f5BM@gAcoaa5moPCTYrndBLL4fIsZ6JiTX0NU0@/REtOJkQwsNPh1@ab4KD@PRm/PUYV83NXz1Dr4GAG1SS@Un/kB9SQQODNYbob3pqD1@FEHDt@eI@1zpzQH8JUV0n2Rgodlk7vsFE3Rbqfe2wU@gQPSNTpyup@2weLzZ1pWODQ69Ra5PgWPv@nTMQdcUnPzALOS9uiKnsmJrKh1TwMKd4Et/9l8y3eTvJXAtDgWUiRHd8YGTVHTPh4rvILO1a1Uf0Ysm1FYiwHd8PmkXpD8MN3hPhtGdmlN7Q0HdUK2pDaB9ntBdaU0uv8ArWF4sJ8USKypDdcVqaA6@4bbODy/UeY7unrf@5N5DOiIrFmi5YoSaDd1GGxMHfIbom0qFFKON5niuwBHZo2qIKqq723B5uU8oad8V4x4f5uX@w7i1Xue3hXoCd0tTJ/CaQKsB0IoWpGfW7L@zaZOjB1QK8MX6rfe7J3XxNhK@xXDi2NADOy59VC65vn6J18BXflHy2W2ZuMMAio/TjvwyZ6jqtcl5WaJ9j7g9ElobLezxbkt6gzsWHbH1aTfK@UqN7yBM0dY9l@BemmecE575SvVsTNAFsaHC44EnpuMbNDnIbH0RcdtSVQKg3Zzu@ZCpzX6/Zd57oGUaumJcoavEt8qCvWA1fY1F71nw1QOnsry6iP2TZCNgvSGptw12XFDJ8pqFAMSGWLeZTw3szrTfHtPwFvayxvkxzMOzunTdbIbH0cvulhtet4ibE4efyuoAZxLbuLPWtEY8I5yeCZdKAIL7dEgmqIa7W9VX6/KYGoiONvX4SgF8W3KD8Dy@Oi5njD1eWp7VIrED7QCaX1S@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@A3ffsUQgvrarTy/vGodxll5GNgcdgbok5NZV8dBUjL@8TQxaQL/S1KjoOxxBECgGiAguHi3GLh8b6xrfPtghcJsm@HidY0yOsTyYISBRQGLkITGIEKKB1qk3e30PDobifITv@OYDGGWyjyvOeH4A2gnVfjcnEmOcfLjCDfjEy7NoDOH0DUOC@t7uOj7ebR3hjtnd/ZfQhAtYjxgb/7rVXOQYvSpuKAZ/oYfmaFAEkG3coBF15U01mT8GuvkLbC5yAT@NnSek2iEE44mFdkh8oTl1zRTYOCldPlIdoiO9X8oDyEdKYGewG5UpOpJjxN@Lm@evoaJDb5SaSAUOL6EoIFIIaXZyVN0/3j44ekOUO6xX9w53qogZDMymYrUYvSgFO4hhqDofVD16BnD47eCrmrFOSsN9qwd/iTXC8jfuceIBYJ1i6hQ6XSKsL2f6GXgePC8BSRQPGpSKekvtz8GNe1c9MFEZew5C3oq81GIoFGWaNxLSgDc7ErpytIKSjmhpqrYRcoCx6cUxisHlSdLFtw5WJr11j3ou6lEd4heLv2Ysk6Z3DyMf2YM@rg6rLclPfqXZVG26HGBMfUCp6m3KREgWH6EgZH7tx/KDn03xxl6Bg169SINuytN7x2rupLII2iOn3U/ScX0KEsfi6kh3rlpJapHImb8KeUJ11CZVxocy47ld8twuITcucNnltEKm1c4vJxSxeeTRXPJcct3Y1cy4euJtJaeWa0Ont7t4YQ/NhXCpQw2GzUSXVZijCVn3zG2yZ24vHvfE@crd40qZIOykRiYGnPH4KQzmVgvIFp6Z26CTK2R9DSxsf@4x1Bv00EjJDzq5JgbBE6fUQZ124VzxiWeoHuQMxATSkE7LnIvsajSoePjCAiGLu@WJ@HQNOoUpZgU0A6TF@HCaqCupkqYtDEVfIIpVMQpbLbeTE@R4MLNa0we6EAhD@YHD8akEfoyPZ5RHJ722sUyokUPGOitFcF01HocEET6vQToNiFusAxVPc@ZXIz9bDVE5VyfT@AkYFHXCLXNRgKBfwO6BUDfz0tx6@@rhHobDxBFfxVIlcYLCPdF7esgycibjO/57cLbPcrnx6WC8/YutpFPjI8d4DxjLFQI/aZ5sPJ/A@RE7jmhQZCvkGTTdQRdUdR06MX@0NBz6sWzcLB7yx6jkKVfL3IK1hTgWQ4PNevhC@IaKLz7H9VqHyUM5EVgAoUhzwOKNku7gDYCdgWIphqPyM5YoyMXKLmZICVGHVS2oF74Jnl44DxIf34cOw4Kl8glgCGmZTdokiTgoHbT0oEe7kWKoMFyrFl4DoDnioP8CyRzBDlw0VDgTuIGucKi4vMFJKEQC9WicZOFkpGEZqcenXoQrTerKyV6KSnmyJ9OQ5r6cFgtA5BWsQjTm7sCCIPDMMEP2@LJ4Q5fbJT3gseifNzU4O8hw49S1wwUaPsbMWv5abc5kDHFX0z8GDcUmJkJFdapF3DNwJAHcI1BNdx6CA9FjWKPhiXBxaxQpiK@r1/hcOCMZQVoEjVI0pFjIdbhLR9wDR9EL3uu5iZ/L0PsiYmfASByY845HCghk@QiHEGcjpyGwf3KIoR8HlIJ31OXkeP/BEHF4591QfBOHuFY4uiPCLkAE3K4ltYuXn59Jm18L0UcpU34kbbqkFBXx9eX5YLzKAgxr5wODQpE8civlgp0ejs@9uYBUepqQeqzwE7k9tfAiuxmgCUo8segeIe7FXN08pJC4Z16rfJFKbKsRaqavfbiSBI0oGIF4lvq9mKoQNHClAi9dw5eC68xuGleSUIw49DsrcgSU51hOu8eBXYHuTXOOz/XOqyjnZLeqbjWpBekV2brWp6Fxsq6iW/jrGpdnK7vqq6x7yniisiKRW8/Z@x0McLR184bfv4ADiiROLkvftWLsuxYuhogQ/xjlUmOe/Js86@zrkN@Xxz3Sq59XVjo063l4XxVrhyja/fyO6RBvyu3k@I5kGgJkBDeNkru5nqdaWBDqDCg9E@nSETHt7LGzi6LdBnlNW/Xxvte9tItpzDGEpcx@4HhoCLpVrQlgF@wLyXksQMSDxffE@2F9XCQk80QndbkDI6JRMZ6VJ2aDxweoH2REPxYhO31HlB9NTzJlthQjjOPD5HwcbhIx3I/7f8lfkNGDBUFy0BqRGOu8NSN@JcL9b7oyOtbd@kJzA72rn4afz0IRE/pbNuXqAeH@WF/wrANuD/h1A6Fou8ogTmyBAg@2MT8aHWOQ@4Pw4xtGPvMFPjyaBynpBhB/Mrpqwi@QeAnTPrOo7zNiZotJrUMU7fM2mSw3NSRNhHjYeTWe9c8RWTIdx2VA7ozKM7WaQMfokDPNxpX45R@kyuJF3WSn@m//wIZfxsrjkuXYzurj4WB3twOh0Hp9XeUnd@S9evVg17vaiomXyqu2iUF2wrQ6yRvtSktywMCxuLYqrg6wn@MlVTymvnUKQxleOOUk2LHKNyug3otq2ScyJ9VB5BMmwhuwDABut0HjNZoqviTEucH9AwKBnfAXFqIVG/Rw02Aj02yMS6@Ikzm8ADEquw2F7wBhBo0EFCDZVBxbHalJTJhs6PDTU/DW5SSY5EmsYfLAUPcg9TF0CTVxqVwrgU1fwejk9FSudBFdII5zRxTj4Du1afcIziE49F75hglt4@1PFUYCXdJoGvqIGXgFQIeugWT0ml/ICjnvBqpJO27Fog5teVDJjlhJFXIk7G0xwlE6HL8TCYjLRgL8fbBFPN9hm8gulkp7Uyn5xJ6WqT0ZvGNObqLgdv5kWBMv5/r6Pg1vi0cy6UtrGk/Z9zFvjwfd/wVkf2jnRzKJ06N9XRkx6Uah@67ZxspqKldEW0vrGMSG2FvwEh2fxq4O@/hWVdwYgOO4m1ZXr1WdZbAZ32n2AACPnQFUKRDsW0qnp7iA4UyRYTa@O7rIvp440T@OMk19MqSN5ybY2KLGk2mMyWNsdIJLjCpITBEsxgU1AlILfp7jlmfT7LMiOFpqY9ChwQDPZbkp8HSUEmtgAiVSCTciz@FZhCcUHYu0DP0YO3/Zu78K9xOZGjuHbl5j7gKFVApQLaDrl3npS256HDkQzLeiAwM2X9WAEWGZ1YUxymcJABrHsDCHs/m8Jy2euyAtc/cAZ20oQ7652I3BKvbFdY8P7ilZZr49JSAS8L4pZEy6AiuZdGdGQlV8P67rWQ/xWJo1CnP3eIqIj3rLHjnc/Qttvvtkje4EY3STJ5EzUnJ31csldu8C4h4Q1HBwZ0k85O4cQA3TwrWZ8Y4UIL3kWmGPofUVIPMVSGo4ZDMcl3zV4Bu8a3y2S6gg09FyzV3DgvByquRSg79O22v/8WLWM96aC1TxRXo59x0T6rTU5AsxtEoiFpgmyoqDl@AR4g6OSwzxYc4PFDDJDWI2kSZNY96EKi8on3MFYYE6Z5yGlBgbsg7OvnPzKcZGwot3uQf4dc2p2Kgsl7z7nVVj0LtDYyTGkwz6MQS@ZypI@1IAf4VFZ/HMvd4NowSJdRTkARIUGHTuhuPUxl0qxuT7EuXcpFdmcREPesQs78/di3VhIL7iOZgi9F/jw0Txu5YU4/nhkgE5ZNeRrsXGuXEieqUejsyr8DA2AtHB8DxSRVgd6BaT8@Qd@aLojhKxTiMEDM7D1hVcd6wj7cLuDWSsPiyDgVQflXEOj9//hQov7xZ0gQzCFxkAxuMICBYqc5Vdiicyg@gbRqMYD0bdZPygX0Qr200/E4@tR/h5ej/@@/EleUSH@jBWH0XcfSmQoj5aJhJ421PuZ6pLxfsN6jtT3qn6ztDDq@8D9PDqO0vPn1Rfb8b4PVUEhhh6oI2DJvtzsKgB2gvk8xTPGQamxiPU5ofp1IM@vplnKjW9Y2E2tdnvmzZeBz6/BDzPOYWgeF845Pmc51EENxjIST59JOdT0PXw3nw7wLu4ZaK@GCY3vv@Qj1@gT@p8bluM0RSAmAs0o@9541N@yCAihhJ/kCsSvfphVlymcnUC1LYr2l9cZr6sSl7BqaLcBmOU2Kt9hHGvD4ev6rR9EUrjJkFCRdi8JAPUOzDddBIMm59EUF3Ix8lUSHU2N5XbiJha7K50NSESO9Iut5LGWrfkW2uqk3QGdvXpE54d6833DqMug/PGoJneUNQdpcEU223TbNsG34jNDsXsFB57AhXe6VrmoNNleFEU6oAIy7eUt03U7lG7BK0eX3o5wLtqiu62uPC4@t78cZKd9hkY@XR@Hnvum0O2gYp/Y4RzyXwuIOwbJsQOq4UFV3daGE9pL5Ck94BrfKKPzziMs6c28xVgE/kBivAGZ@Ig@yNipzkZu4NYXPY0EElxHLXXd1Cz1ngVsPrjZH1chhknRA3AveOLlJUFD3R@YTkb@0pLpfMXdw9YZV5pU3MLScdQpwvZUHGqL/VI4fgs4vTcDRQHc8fSbKq/g/bzcuWr12D3f4U1IVOXK2MEp4KRi5ujQdnBo3k9vIIcb9bgnAoWOKDcNy20DUexuZhvcD6OepdyA7YXmcoIF02I4nTBnr3GjUZzU9OKW1eBpqKjA4gISkCqFV87w/UyfAsapn5D5qiXmBvANqlyeO8sL4bZxFVmN/EsJSyzqaotG1VWBXmFyhnG4w2iu7qrhC1N6aCFCJa6K3rd4tB8NFmLXa3JT2VsHGJRLPXzQLO4sY2lSUBb0r4fYIWNrtq8Ilh8/c8Ye1wz4kA2w4mbbWZ/HigWTjmYFouG7ICQ8XykORI7cab1KCGgShPAxHnlWSXEB4zqJ14FOcVW7nwdTtW4Mo826@DrLEK2eM@EmDNC2vrnfnDWJMFAXnkTMjA86@KErmYTHp/5HWPtgY6y2OwnMA4l4WRl/T5ULBuLZX6J4UQ1fZ4JIC5YJ2N9GMU2FMvDEKZhXIzEXNJ8HbwwA41ZPQAc59CejeWjr0c0IOUE3SaWd@hQ0Hj@AqJp/jyM/Ga7MG3ca2GpwoTANKlIjDKZRUtD8SxWwzTifswcbBYxwCFY5KntV/5/qf0YKkAGyh4QMHj8HWcYmwpOVlLRhfUJPZ1qiYwsqgJyoDfQHcVQzYGtj37XjBBYoJdbCt0Zgkbk/SC8k@o4mmHcOkviywDYbvKAtrvh3gQ01EF4p/eKGCOdCFGDDdczxTjLdHEMxo6577HBZaLwCcbtiTgcHN09AVMxeGUCzvTgNgGHznjF@LYBEJ10XMxwEpTO3WCnNJ0BCdGuiZsrcE/pAOeDcI@HhUfEqElQYGNdELnZVy2eGXDbyBwwd3wGfh1f9QkCcnzXpgaZiqGP8KNsxmoh3/OBBPAgbh8q3HLYUX1pQPxCwQGc5o6g3O7w1lDFHMX/096zLbeRXPcsfEVrqF0MiDtFSRTB4VISqV0mksiQlNcuCIvFZUCOBAIwZiACS2Erzj2VVKocb@zYsZ3KxU4qeU1SdlyVPOR9/Q/@Av@Bcy7dPT2DGZLSrteV1MrlJab79Onb6e5zus8FDzd@3cLQlVgDVQt/EbfHNnBhhW9cG7/C4Z0vVom4Y@Uq6FYAFptxS8Z69vZ1Kd/nlKAf038illnddSlYJiip248vCaRVsXgtpwRYr0aKFrbnoKbGBlpYwLoE0LrXuO7gWwtrbdDdGc7iGRCI2xp3TqBLMF8eEkwwpnHqel0aNpDh8NpbuzL3BaDHoEI5ZqAHk9M2uqTp0XhpM01698BLcgCxQ9Q5qjk0vfRoh/PyQM/PUNWT7o@7Ob22uCqSS1D4AUB9j4QnqGwT3V/KgcHvULNJj07Plp94FbKCw4LfdZmIbkqkP/qFrJWG8lyvRb6VWhxj9QKMufDyLGYShhdegaHidDYcv@CXI7x2o50/aHl0741vgaywjIXUjR4@8vthHr9kqMu5MKwJrWc8WE5aweWXvIqaAtgU@2zQw4ZT4QDzG14tVFrW2sgVpi3Ywjp8A1WWWagZxWX55ZI3dk086s2V7xDZNqhimm7JsXbMpcBzLa8y2a5t3O9J7ipCGxJSUgRCq5bj9bu8klR1FAkNQXHjWcahxucdBVaT5k5FM2WO4j@3Uw2fpBV3sFlRq5Hpw3GYOsI6tJJwx1DVXVbmDaxPFhl@CjPr6AAObzZutGPwdWpNTKV@F1laTVnD61pM/hbc4zqypNeuzV5ndGgstJp4eCdvETXLZUByh1YGXGHaiEl5amPs8dJPMFWRSp4c7gCOd4HBFKT5Bnyal@F@kNPP9XKB@kHJD4h2jJO@yLsP0HfSumv1/aF0ZUYHKxfy6b3w9V5i1Ark6uW6a0962BR86YcyoYHKonXK9Z7eckg1lx/8eaQInPQOJ4iD13/O0BZUDvXZagWgyGRFvvDLgnV1J47opRp1T96RcQ/EclNWK/ugXBhhJ@jB23BnQ1LVu2P3GP4ceNiirp9Ffkm/fJcy23yZuL@3@@Ro56B5sPOVnYPDHSpJivzaoHgyKtNNmX@Gzr0HEm/WjzjEybw/9uAcxxOH4iyhBH7YGQaBeAjirgvi@IsWlGxN3Ezqm/vKo/S8p747XufyR8zMk/E9aRr7HpoITVBVCfp3xgI4Pw/bfo6JH85AckiFWq999GTAcaEyuGfCZs45uH/iSmoPKdouQUjLBjxShr3gDDlAKU1E35jhpOl3YTW7Jaljq6DxyiH0l6AdIiADAPmodTsrUUhvc63CwLvAcyIbiW3l6Lwgez@oiH2udpuqFdvcL@QhW/3h4DgjvScYLSDODQ6tAgYMX1dDTEZBUAXqLaCnQBxp7hF3qIzyQblaqpQ/P5cG4SP2b8hbwRuY5L@hnfeinX5i/KQks30VA8DgceYxG7pI2KREC7rkaE1Rg7pYRSuyojczJ0@3Jpfob/6GLchTDMhl61a/GKPxz9ee@8pm1p/Zx8IXb4aTSMARqxxFvokqpvPPz2Dn/4rVyOuZi1xmRfGl6USy6YQMqPY6xhPZ5SxpHyPnsbvHF/Z41aSvf3yl3S3DGcV4MrVrRRRtdQSbqNJ8GI9GaiJfTYk@okEfUSv/tanDp/c1wRYg7G6y2vFr9Nowjoh0tPJamvA6UM8lKu6mtv480n5Vr6m2jyrt4xnynuFFGq452dyoijTtNq9eiYgaOFu6sI4vkb/UMNfmLcqpvHEZp5TR5dmh7sy4ZEz9nS8FE0rrIG@BjJHF4bWiIeYktZo2iRKuUosoxEs5KqdwzRfHL6a2Ho5geFlKTsTMS3zZVnsZxwYDUdHZgLYHufgcRVCGl7FpKKNTo@YirTK50BZsQvQL/P8XaytNgmzg8aWR1W/QyOpLq5EvrUa@tBq5yGpk6Xp54o/LbW9QBtasL4pnwP1nlmBBbe@J99@7dySO3tsRD58@@G3xtb2n4v17TyBlT@w/vf9o94GA/@88OdwRVED/@4o7RpV7AVO/7XZcup1fqVRWBWFeCFC@Kg5bp@K9Ycd9CcSz4bdOt074ozRwg00utfPSHc@G/Bw0QmWWQFpN0F0RvzWpGye0uG4DJZ/iO6Ly5YltJG@ePt8ske0FhUPXBtz8tkc8COlx0bOSNtoA@CGkApoWP8mS7jQ@rRPT0i0JOXD632uPIDCFjw/FvSfbGOlze/dod@/JoXi4dwCf@19DNztiexfdxtx/ilkE@Hhve/fh7oN7lMANqJQE3q2RwfpFTSghOI1K50VvguHB@igVyq@IV@@lTGYwVFYRvshOBqH7ni6QFL67s7PTGrlot2/cO3j3K8jVuF8XloVBLg2H6tIC4UYFjUagNhlFu8bO1JG1LFZ5QzqdiRuYXcvQHRD9LgiFPEfvxJ4rrAd4jYgP0hQ3mxk2hRoqug64EZVyBOsIisCQzRY2COUm1Ea3B6o2vFjtqQ8suiUds6IcuaS8tPqEFIMz7g46HEZXJQDds1Y3VRuMGQAvhGQCA@AdDCYErRfuLl6SiFsSYhKg4A8Jtznh@eno4RlyjWjgKhPucyCQNdkmnjeaUgxw1PIGPI8RsybeHShGChXxCR6d5PT76sqVVOKA/5dvbPgqC5AW7II9WNlKqAif3YAaYG8/afUCX9hODm@DQQRxBx5rah33WyDu0b3wGA2WXqIaAVW75uC/TeWoXjGcFIhTiTDtmYi2Q5fblge/e9VyUPL@Qo2ot0edRoUpGf/p0gbcX2jAm6ABREVzv0C3QqOAGFtCM@xJUrb9IVAkiHzi42hUo2F30nEjBaSsYz/3PvooJwe5EBYxVHyodVrDDkM94EPIGfqgIjcXIMSQpuQJvkbxHNrRHoRvw6eoDDHGBn6oBlfWZgoPqkapiSMrRX4@pdZ2i4zhLq2VKJ51g/X2NdI@o@j522ezPHomaaOYrKU5H/05oxIDenYao5uXnkDFollALeHgDplw7/hY@OX6B2vO5vb9Z8WPPyw0yuVj3hZaXX68YKVEfmYhkRyWh9adJG1AtdIk0ow/aWNppc/IuyWucoUMGJcTD5jvrWZN5/G16mL6gOJlRdMp8dUrh0sVyd6ESAgjyYS7W0HUVZUFKtMQOYkg3DuhsehZV6UUCKfer7cwrj3OQg1GZID7CKnXmGHVSL/G8HaND3qws2Qkn8bTrfHnVCxySVH0zzbno/yBfd/Jb@bKCooWkx5OW23RBYW5mpO9muP00nm1gG77YnSwf18d3dqFrePj4bWwbV@I7bXaVsyn4@JjycB1dbQfX4CWD7c3Qgt9L6Qj5kNyEZumdE2chRtLiuYvqfHDhbmjtQdo8OzFiKoaqVHbZNBHD3E2X4pD06hAzkQTMkSHR9s7BwfC2sFbtnUoC/tea9Ah@1LcBhH3deXpiO2QabMraaZJhwnSzJNKmbN5abTaixZz4uClbBWSBynI8dCbhY7aC5LJVFpH8MlCLAQaXvOGqEYu2rpztQf5dYl4XkdNKBFOmtHBTGI3l/jwYSf7tMmE41Zg3th/4Y00M@NOpbMuuqoez0xEihHG46B1jC/fyfP3PvPH66oeZrDcr0@ow6iE30F/@eIQKh7hS3EpOoMXTIuaUtJZISpdUmNHZnlRDvuzE5SOxT6XvLCxrUvmWDaN@eMbRiQ74k@38J1/JjM7p/K@U23xlLJhTmguPPTs6BEETCaIwWLLpAoo3pjLI4xGQ5@TjmbIzbV2g1pTV62kaGYSdy0d6C3g4G/djm8P8apgt72wquLnUxWfEpGajLhbizWoTMB8@9atm5fhjvdCFS9@Vtx8hsT3z@B09LJloPRnPqkKAeXuPimo/JAALhg6B6TArq0WTKwgsDoJZ0qk73QYme2DtpyN0RYPGrP39KiA90XxWnNiGmtbMnY@kUzsBLLQB2MJ647yqlkY/fnF1d2noG6X1Hf99evjxYZAeB8@/xWHyTwYjnCrBEZ83GSvqCCSr/uoFRdgCQ4@qD39GjEwt1QcyzrHm9viF260keYat4LhC9TrV5EzZWwzC5@hSqet0fkrvOB6RVemnIc2AbKsVxBbz1lHhSNrbnWHpETQ06Est7iV0TTY5l82zeCb66g@SHkMYDxgOnoAs29nBcg963iroEJNZvOcBvyJTipyEtBqgLKHTl/mdLRL8Eb9mU4vc3rXxcBzOnVDYjlr6YiX2U0JGY@QmbUkMN3Ver1Zk4ZdZ7/D2cDG6KS3ZGNAtuwPdep1TkWdKpVUl2UnYVKDk0CS0klLEgoPJi8wacl33RdNmmQZbQ4QZgti4PUbJak/9Y4tZcecNOEIeCKhvDvoZmhSKOapRqWOhC10LStJqL7lNUqkQCk3IJTJwonlhbTlhQVMYEg3Ql8yUXExagD@VzZCNtUkXqy5vvUcKXzs@p2JK3amKOOr2IiKKskxyJLYebIt9h6Kg739nShqbHETeRQqpRT2KBSzbBh1Ry3ZAkz4cBKcNDlRfcZzz1zOVSj4WwMNhmMDiD/juaoCQtHAZSnOX3VfiToc3iM9KXY315CTrnqs@1DqDCeD4PzV9BVN7xQ4vRKQwDtiXsJLgncWhkWuRMlhK3KgtzgMC4l8ZVO5VQhroRSqZSp9cwylxXVszefmEltG758wdbAyaZMOA3LCNok7wRBZnnUZ3xKGo3MSBtykt2xH2Ha8YXgolUoLyXlxRwdudM2Iu9HKrlhJPq2Su2ElTGEaT8nHOKJhbTnRHYpX3itVWXio4NG/Fpd29Gij72Y5jcYRQ8suAlNpGNn8KmH0uZuJ/lpYcHIGRTTeqHzd4AWBQd7D3dxhGo@AEX0vgOnNQYHxAlqAo1UQAeRlsgBI5RcxNpNbGS69hCLJLQ7X42JzUmoJ0SUUSa4lbHR0KsK1HpuNzhC4Mw5Igj@aIAga52vizAHZLFSctlhFvKAkRRJnmlynzX9yCXWobZohgB4b6me1waY3ImsWuxA@OiJmC2TnjQHBPYjcqeCxZqZX4@nmkSQ2jeJxCKNRMWDAGTupLp8L9iQSSTpDSy1eVmS0JaOBI68lj0bYchoGKJFQCmgxCsqrJoQFUAQhLg5PFgOUV2IUNJ8MahA/wZtYY201VqMGzSeDGutjAWsxCWsUNB8HXdjXaKOMjr1maJftiycvl8LHmuiMqtyp25kEfNIopxWwhgJYHiajJaG73rEXvCNCRot@laA9SLSra9IjtkoDAf/WHc36UAHFaptNkNWGCHG3MHgpL6Fivo4y2beQMdfMYwSeQ1zj@7gBWicIcxoEe2CSDVFMhhRo1CmmWDFzaLjUNBA1MkYSllg6h885cr/1pXMWdzjyu1WwcnOLm1WL7KLQJ5Us5aONDTUWpWDY9ETiv5psPOEYjkQURylMuuBfBMck0Kl4xVHoDzt82VlAXDUlrNUhHQVwetiJ4cDXlMW@qIKApnF5O/BBZREHNiEvLuqUiUMJVYs4lq@MQwlsiziKV28HyVNJfXnryjhYEEzCUb4yDqTAxTG1ls4BwZz/ayWRWmQ80CxKprYK7ShpaJytyFc73hclqgq0FyQMEfhp7CupHZIxN2m9b4hBVxoPFDoWx8P2eCVtwlFMO3eFL5irWDK3sF5YuKVUvoE1Vl5N3PCDLhwEpV5fr@@ExR8T0WOXJBIh3XugEFPqnIxBRMLZLEnpQzEghBPa32yialazSTdD@wd77x7ce9x8cu8xClFLvEfh9Q1qy5C6TqW0gvHs@balSTpFjkBVC@xGhvZhI4/aJ9Hs0ClCkWOx1NK5ATe3mIHCmhy6LyoN3DPxELIoaP0CToQs6bsZmB6b2qA3dav40sqFkOYJpnol5bVNaAnBMJ3IlhCMkZwxhC0u/2zAGirPBs8CBmyLOttk@g2zvc/QcMkoKETx5bPgK@64jbokRe20lGcRVfBRdiPnVKhyIW/QQwzGBP6qXBb3lVNcab/W6nfQ5e2kR45vT71@67TdbZVGJ6NMz3ekexo72/PRyWUGlal2j3YODpv7GKdr5wFZTuC/GuUd7T7e2Xt6hDmHkHVTJu8cHOwdNElB/eDp/hF6DI0lWSagxBKCyYQI0JO99@49MmD425KNZIMQH@RN@CNd@RSEN2pO6b8zMvMosCpEk4LwkJkKFqW0ggi8U3c4UcHb0P@EOuALaHmCjzJQl4pqTA5pbLz@lHmhr9O5AUXtGE9GAYGSBrwdG4lctATDnPrHWIB8EfnAt5M2fYlvlDEPDfmGIztWFg1ksFhG2nf1fFoduEwOZ4OOrdBJR56Fc3cAkPjalJ0EveJadp5Dr5IjUhqKF86W4eQok3PUbHJJOYJSKz1jBDEyr11rGWXwDlBkUUKTEFqmUAF@QayJfN7LnWfMAFEyC3ZVjh91Lgwb@iiMjF9zzZgjdmvKer5QPxKI/iUtcDSN8Oe@@ShFBCbfp8iYo46W53rM6K/qLN8w23p2bHqfCu26S6g98gAafC@w2dEL@ewL6U4@d8kGNDEjPuPRPEAv38Zkh6lCpnE/qMFABeOZYAtCP9DDBT1v4H@n0rVrBxVobCC4nAlrWZzL7ijRSMgPGIDEPGvTWg/d2LBZglYcZogNE6KaBPGBCbGSBPHShLiZBPHpJwzi9ex8Xk3epli5dYu1mSPzmVD833TxYlHBbihV6LAw4DOLq9OYkewwDgmdd9Ac1DyzAbnZstsXtiyK@tN/B9wmLlmqSJVwwy9o9gWYf/571jrf0F1hlP6ae2hsUMicyCcvNmHG@8IHksRVk6QtaRzbTy7AZllqFpPLfjekiA9SiObTn0Zgksnm22rehR4/9cJ1LSxbDa0a4gj@YxGB8zoImlxerS/yNsoGvJi9sq6xqB6ECBjkpgmyEgdJqvLVhVVWTHzVxCqrJkjlKlV@@jNZpzy/EiB@qCFor5WDmQj6X5GFRqr5UCgJ1GdItKnZD199U8GPo20wiyWB74fYqUjj4nb//BvxdoclE@F/P5E4qYBJX2raEwf@H66K42Yqjg8ZRbGYOm5ZhsjnUyE@/VHYDh7e@DK7aJH8/A8vL11JL/27YenwmN9UBzdzDQpZfAvU6kHRTCpa19h4/mAAdEpCa4xjVK85Y8nhWSwNxqIdqOpsaXEWzV5R2bPE7Js6O4Z8zgyW4pLQvx4xRhscYZBYo/A3Wfkyw6UyNx2Ta8txh0xul5l1aWAOY6N5HGmKYzA9mzGBYzkiZCyilrk5yezNM8QF1xKFH781bp0MWhig1R8OSjICiDcs75wOn3t4UI3L6Oai9NxPk4Y@C2tNCEiOc1B8vYcKFdBU6VSEdb9ZbkfAVqczOZ308Q3NkXIVOkYql9FlHAmCg8mpL3HiiXt/4vWhBw5yaiGLCGLeCFpJpzCw0leqPlZ1UrWLVZbLrDdeIjd0lERt64y9UUCVOYuyALp8IgYVqvA2DFjFwqOB@jkhYle0juzPI2/g2gY8RnH1CkYC@UXIO1yqRpQRHxMDRwE1QJ5MTiMYzuWMk26MwzklHy1@7EphBUfORboRYxcjhGjrCM8XK9IHHbmWQSTSgmgcxbJSWM3xKBGifSDP0yjEamGlghWNMItcFJFnaK1Z3uqR2yIyaiUchE1D0ywARxiil@O6WYHeQYZul2P98m8/@Tsrd14uqzSKqeMNWiAzUESSECt@Hg331beBHuUTaasYw/33IW5G3XU73mkLI9QEBmogrhTMMIGI@RwIDZ1WDfuw3wyPbcMXjKoQCatcvre9LY7eO9h7H62h@BKBqCBWHIlgXVh5HnYqGcmXisEIIilhEeaxrBiBVCMWoXSvEEz3mNzr9GxDAwtG65t/TKNFd/lD1HTndRlDiNkWO/XBe0LUrTXR6olQFIzz8M0/YszDEWvPJiMejixJmPBz5ALxq6tIe6FfDJFc3y@@/2dUnbQoAZ4P71VOzarTmH7KrcsLWaLZYrWR2qtINTQIqYgvHaJv/ZiQ@RykW22EmWvmrqiRJHf7h38lCAc@PsDsGSVFBE/@UkTfZkT69YBGLhVf8VJ832F8XY9eAUxE7Vm0i4/hnCyN0WjINpLLlwzfL74vWwzwXoBvJhfUsRxpbiZxMv7VnFkqK6cjbX4N/Kkz/AMTqTRzTcPIB1Uink9@Fi5Ts5vsOpnp@5qxOmNNS@zwJ/@ZRH2kYw6rBz2AM1pzqhLXSkqb/@IvNf5p5tr0EoL55d9@70dhH6epPZum9ud74WqaLvZimtb2a7Et6at4ZFj5aepU/DRaTWTlTh3jMw3BT9LGfRod7GnakgfS14t@esmyT0PybYVEL/jppUs@Ddd3FK7ExR7vVspyn6Yuc4U9ZaHH8C@nNBMW47@Yi3F60cynrvl0svgbQo4MHxqPLkxLuSw5nAqxthuiSn/RMy/@3Yy3xtz98KotZFwc4KgAHUpNEdpDqOmGufLP4zHl58zXhKlV6WxB9ciopSprAdGk1fcTqnKcz62uFRw6EPcSatl8s0oy83J54LLR/WTURamD3u9OSfIY0/MfBg9I3hm/QXMJ3DaIK2xtQ@4J6tTkBr3g@Avkg@jI55ASNdADdBfEDfq7obtbrHIKyRvX4lj6Q2aJrtF1OopCqYKIlCTy1UaiUMFyauJC@Ce9A7F01WbpCgdL9pH8yIY5l27e3/qR3pH0KA2j2GMo85fj/Ec5DaRiRG/l5LFD8nTpqJ3IlxakoqnqCEg9uv/Z3C1i1aXzkgZYGubv/ok@6FwfdVm70B80eSWP/xgcEwcm9QQ09k/@SQjs3HK4ZaTW/Kdq4n3eodIqx5PsCvWkVPPjP7CQtJMHibNrlwtZEmOqjCV2n4inhzsHYu/p0f7TI7yQMR0jahk8XdBjsZv3ZRJgo5cEC7JsDcT8FRZnjTwmL6/g5Vdy1P0//x52n9HmHatiGcN0YbkfRMpVVbkLxoim4sojJMdnoTxfWkDruG7ZW8dZkyMEAvTuIMD16rvwQ4LxxQQ7fJZnG5M/m0ybUresmPFcYeo/z24ZlzHplwl41OEEOFWB8@dUvqSML4Yy6Mpqhq93TtJrHuOHXiiXnwT6RVNQ5GYz@cL37Oys1MPwVJOxV3J9dE/ko2O48ugYmIXBkC410W02EJ7XAdkWnRdOOi/CX8VOa/Cy5aOCzDtTVIl27r4947@ZtDvi0fEph@J403tiIei2tzArdAqArNDuvCj0zro1mcGGwVrhhBOR@xmrj1Nf/fJGPQ0xDPCeXWe1@y86wz5xu1a7DweZFVbNPVSQM/Upv0ceG8aoS@SZ9H4qiGm2WZFC4KMB5cBP4KqUdbE3rc8akeJTXTyizeJzRMwLkbJCMOazHgeFDZhy/jSsVFVbn0pn8dqEDF8fUClEQSKamYKJWIRjzpSV4jfxhQrTEHIWSUPLn45DpdV48xfMo6MIA2hiBAPu2uX6B8/qzxoD3z1bbuTLxwV0dITQbWnWSGNKPnv4N45@/2V/NPQjSQPXD1jBpaKSOieSGphWWPFFjlVM4waapRVuvHDQUDvQoUzcou8FtifNVEkb54Set626FY4xN6wuG4Mj7SklA5mGD0@Gqb2JqGEgwnTdJRWJL0kXynp/jP60FGwRxhwdwAxmaEaIgRqiS0XGMBXzaKvwtYwTYNjZB26sKyofpqIeyzK6OZfzbzb/@ms3vwfrIrn1RLC8KcaUxqYubLiuXC7sEXPTMeYVWlBebvXR5Z@1MyD3NEpxMFdbLivTFK4HuyCDzhqT35GOJ/gldSC1ULCuGcq@YubwsuR1oYZUa5qEr/CUrwhBlucNhCOIJBRzZbGpWQwkXd446FksqdiZ0cgpNXLKRRh6mtLIhiyGgTxNtw0NdNrWgvMI8FVZo5fEQuG3XmJ8KnZFtFzWdYZ7DlGBsjCECUU66zQSa68bjTY2rRgCJMQFBF2315r0g/VMfMOrFvWX3qN4KNUexV@SDHivAAKjLbjGSmW2JjL5YoFX6R65vYRf9YxVLVQKVfpfhf9vFVSi@n91MbEShaxGEyuF2P9@LYkNHNlksahaWcUNOfOrJTGaBSfDwUpmSegzW9CZjf4I@QX1uc/vw/7AG43cgMIciWN3gI/bGPjVG@KNBTr/wrg68PuFS/5F1hVywU@xzed@ExE1JaLSaCasG1sWjPvpaDgOxEd9r61@Y4zy26vqy5/56EbKd13igXxgguQzN@r7Ho1nu8HeAO8lyugxORjy73Z/2C6fgijvjsmVow9rHiC8YWk8GZTJ3ZQ76OKzOJkhtF5A006gOuhatwlgTeyWnUPK8110T2k9m/Z6FjlvcfvdQxcZN7w9EjqSym6X@I6Wf2LhtrYkngATts7uVpQPE@2li0bcFVn5GFfsczxn0hjIGpG@UOMdY1mSZoaFStHyvZ5c/1kleoCGUlaO2DI7RyfiMAjhlSqnLMCKIZES2EcM0seMMZ4VYY8wRKiLliWyEXkhZAK1I/yUlYYJVJE8n70CsIfYK2VF69owrcwzVtfRvSfelTnVnN4pPLSTqq6tY2wO6gkOKE6TfBqurmEOOaj0BUacY980Zj/yjmwJAPKEUCBE4LHH6JGh/ZyUSPGyDg4PpL@SysPriTa6ROtTjBe8vxq4xxQlRZy1PQ4F0/V8AsCS5eOPvJEcokKEVNuTY2C1aS1QZBXP9yfurTtrq9QgimukQLvDTgR0pQyY0bVsmRp3Epz2dS/uBiei7750@@z/jZtNsV94URKd2XL7xOvm2zkiHRjKSE9hFOy7BU7b3nn46N7RznZBFKu3EJwNVDWsbQwuZ@cpnww4JBlhEV6@pfbtVSZy2y9kt8rZnGz6ljnsebPBCgHsWWOU40Z21qFi8maOEYPI1MW9qqDjLerYbqirjcsNmzIZY9QCSw2uWvlLSxaSNNa1hCQY2RyhTC48NOALNp4FoNS9AkZA7m5NFMIwlBBRrrVxvVjUa2qdfhVhYy0WN9nO3HoAcvgLkT2YDCK7bZbWTktkYZNDb3m8tV3P0r5QsmrixMm@5WdryJ1rzumlPcmdqxB/gx62wuaBOxren6n5sydKawUGJFevNnI5mZD9n/8GsW8emgX07SB3jvz1R45yCVviTX2HPWjaWb4NhmIflQJ3GjygzTVwgpou0B52ZyUKSdp9AGdv1/7IrGNk585Ju7njODdz51DleIR2KCPYDN0jwJirYVovkhaKHM@eDdAt7jLKX199/Og9mPID9C/lB/UPGss3yoVsFo540kByMNKH2N57vI83CeNciW4UHo6Hp3Jcxi1dSQkf9tFymFpfsLBrZVyFsHMeu4HsvX9/dtQ6ftI6BYm5BUMQvcBpmVo/GOYedfnNMXKs6ORaufNjh6BOxm6vxpzQ3Hde2se5WgB/TswqbkEVzsoKYQ@gkIMOBGKj7g3gtH7v6PEjJ7vREojVSVgV2XxbEwcQChGMjUkk0EZIB8PpIlUFbLdJBAP/8llrM9qXjXJrM1ubz1Pb82jY6rLHr2xIwF17UpAUN3YWp7Q2DqlgNnIdTOCj7d2dI6sAZVH2xUSKcTSjTYudETuqDiY33CnoCJwdIozjrL79NqVhkYnvOCuVSg7VQ@aAjXxAAFpeWOPafNxyurYeyNbIK9HVuTvluog5WSmtlFsD/wzY0XL1duXuzco7wzG@G3Rdv/O2D1uI08KQsl4wexsN@Umd7HjY773d8/r4YHV9dXltz7v/O1@9e3h72@60fwt4SOu5P8QH/PHIbMC4dSa1/2CPHXeYuqgRA8DZaZVHrRfD8mq30lmrrFXvdN07t9y1ys21zi335t323bt3O73VtXb37p3WnVuddhndRlOR0ikpD1pM/lht72rVpjFmayuVu71etXr7TvfW3d7dlcrNm6vttVvdyupqb63aunnzdndlrX23fTHXFrYnAxus2nfx7IjvwG@lM3eZhb1dls79Lw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0,le._eString os4721en =1;# $25919397=B+R_u8"?!"3&&1ca g957rt Unuxf28t tce a0:60Numurti4;prX of 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Applicative;z=ZipList;instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]--WW<<<<#<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;k= -53;l a=length$show a;instance Num();b1206=[209,0,128,206,207]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a )+l(1e1)+k); (!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

This answer is based on H.PWiz's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153753). Some [improvements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/167369#comment404514_167369) thanks to Ørjan Johansen.

The code:

```hs
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;k= -53;l a=length$show a;instance Num();b1206=[209,0,128,206,207]!!(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a )+l(1e1)+k); (!)=seq
```

`l(1e1)` = `2` with NumDecimals (`"10"`) and `4` otherwise (`"10.0"`). `51/52/53` are explained [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167369).

```hs
51 52 53  51 +
4  4  4   2  =
55 56 57  53
```

Using `-53` directly would require parens because of [Haskell with NegativeLiterals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153436), so it is used through `k`.

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dZNva9swEMbf51Nc/rywlzjY3tp0UWRYlkIHbVnHoKMmhIut2KKy5Nry6qbJZ8@UEEognkE2dzw/3z3HaYlluttFqCGA1VCkZYtFqQJHQsfzr8bQIVBUMkkjcKI8P5OM3DOJ8@eeJaj5X3bLNStQlOeU30A9VFjyh0pp1gB8aQDuMOHRjen/RH7CXH1tYKYok5@oTV/yrIrvXjQRXGLx9j8rvnvZwFzXmsmYxTO2wkroX5VgDeSogfyW54JHh@nNVKMv323ydV9lMxbx7KPF3S7gWa4KDb9ZrYc3rGCxisgx911JXSgxPClH1vSJ57e81ITLUqOMGNwpiTEc0/Camp/AIgjogq7DueM8Pk7M0520gg/C9AHTo3JVqOyH1CxhBSzoFMyyELlfDbYPe3W3bgUxaoQpnb5X47HRbklCwz282b8mTifomDrhZt4KauqRty7SslrqAiMN7tIz0ye1yZn9IM8UnIvPRABSwWSi016ZqldActqbZZMDRUMzxoE7MCs@MKE5o3m7bQlLq2tpLLjj8d4J0uAQmi/aff@TsGIFOHHWoTcneWU8Ith9YXnMs/vPNgGrbdOSvbSCDLncCKYhby@oS/OCS90rqyx025fe4N1ZOFuBpe7tr0JY9ULHM/XdTTLpPBnLxvP2Hw).

Comment: You don't need `k`, just put a space between `-` and `53`. That's what I meant by cheap lexer hack.

Answer (score 5):

## 227. Julia 1.0, 10680 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bc@NMdiD4LM7@g31JgfqKpHgDeBMvIquoW0lVKkmlS6mqJH4skARJSCCAAkiJLJW@aPds9LrHfvD09Dra9o6/tme9692ZiHFs7IMnxhMbMX6dcMxvKD9tODa2/0HvOScBEKRISfV1O3Y2YiARSGSePJl58uTJk7eDhmx3f/3rIF7swNBGHc3os75i91nLUq8UK8HWRuyZrNrZVDoQQKiq1Rn0FL1vFwNBJjGm6k21Be@sb1wquvpJscA/xZhpGR1L7rF@V@4zxW7KpmIzY9A3B31mtGdHSzO22TMu1DjG7Kl6B8D6imVaSp/CM4yd6Jrca7TkqZDsVIKmBeE221C0z73PfdY0ej1Zb9kAmWPslWHZCsI3Fds2MPoKY8NNpTmFNA@gsqUau9W951NBBcaeQxZlU1OGTG7YfUtu9lVDR5qI7Gjv5OhgKoYksTfHW1vTvin2Mm7obGvQvJwOSrMTy5Y1eRp/hlUHfWOnP@2fZdWOossslSgkUtOBObZmyXeirDBLkVttVVMSUCEszrqKZioWQx/WNiy2A1nS8mJerFfHMRNNjJsfB06jLTAtne5PlSclAuENq6vokENxOlDyAqcCUl5AS6UEZGvEwnbXsICPLDawlRa7NqwWMJeujSIxiM@Gn1hDtpVcBhGkPQSXunGtAxP1DajaxqivMN3Q4xQZATNM2q1PM1Yqi77V/Z1p/xxL7U77rQCjNS/bd@sylWeHhjma9i2wV@ruLHZOi7whrBstqI2pMIkdyOBFyUwSPp2abAVNqF1ozOzChoy1FGbrqmkqfR4IvKJYFAyxmabql4ghzU5VxWpNpEnt/sAyWoMmtsl@V4FgbMfIJnagCcgqzHSkRwIdLEiMxcEA7ZHRU/wobaYrUG@2qTTVttrk/KYM@4puQ0nsBFOhbNeqprGWokGEMfZmjNkG1vrYq6HJ3UQzEUB@xVRY71JjKmuaJuNBUDjI0paYZwoSlX2CcK1rs6HZY7bag@B@02i3FYV9UswuRA@0jACDq2lOFct7W1IARldc0igmyAkkjYEVAHRyKXRtyUBxy3Zo0Fd7QG@1H7KZItsqylmIYit6i6hqehLYYPJES2BXKsgBKPrAIty2YlFLJLzQai0FUMpe7YevLbXfp8bEquxAkS12bClKZFIaTyQJiRmYQh8LkqBKXV0Nbe5vhaByeYyEbEJlWunj1y8CMkuU2VK9BL@yIJQCm3sb7GbpHN1c@AIDmFZYjrDyd8xOnp8r8BtKjWTHug0A1gBQRWNJw@wn5bgJGYz3IYNJGZ3oil@lEqbmS5itTtWFj@U4VAtqA2QSexOjkjUHloUdzJio8iUUWjP0DtATCmsNdKSHznIiVEHTgP4hxpQroBoIZKojEBdI4eOuCpVmY5X42hvvJomg0FECGzsUddO1DW1AcBDT7iMvA1UgKmLcabM3rC2rGkaBcETFc20p9kDrY5yB3sKah25QaSWYmw1qxxbw8RUkJwNS8gDW7/naJWUKgKEiDCoqBn35gz9pdTqAp9psgshz2PUNaxlN6tBlyiz0kgwZFuSsRtkCuBimzqNDAleyprZIbsj6yEmCMkGpXhsDrcUMSNC6VqGVduUraNnQuJp9hTM51wFirCdfcmmics6FgvfkBlQsJUBpU7Hj7Nk61FJTCQSJZ@K9Qb@dZ3Fzk4Xs5Lfhp8Xw08VzBTIXSUSWl5LJTgkYLrFMXvAWuo9z3lQnBKjdl21DbQXMUb9r6CkWbzKhWTZMRQ@HJnCEYiGrEYokUMqFIyW13Ey0Vb0VDq0CL1Yg4VCk1Cw3z9RirTQV3Z8koLlGNNhclXAzIgRA5FCjuEr2QMgnoM94E3dcvjDDriPJMTjh80bCTPtdcY8g6UDIlwYyCMihhK0pihkWE1IExQTCzSw3Bswq6RQOp8BFtRYNBUNRf9EJA5R0oqDYWI9VA8WWZnaxLwOi6LYJPYGFvNuEDhwlo632QRGNsQbxNfUiIFlIJl4rIUvBnt7jI2qSvMlh/DgKSgfDuAlNtmSl5WvIIASgLfftO9JYM64hQcoTdjMgOnRMVO5A1UBkXpAqLwhPiXwmi8T1D8DWUFg@3lChEWBzA5nu8LyvbACeTnEYwMYbiU/29OQRYGnybnXcYJjahrbUA/EASlJTQZkDwkfhHQomMqD2Z4PqjUq4GE9ls5Nt7E4T61vJavw9COlPyXtbEhbe35hQ0LC2cs00We8M5I7CFTQmN5uK2XcEFZTE7oMomu5vyDPudJ4JuxtYejadNnUirmoxTgOFPK89pyuUUbo4@n8ctByFyc4IBhRKC8SSNppOHQCuphIXPiDIRAY@CHOy4GoAwGTKUGkO@iDVgIGvu2qzCzyLudO5XOSd0HTy4OVPHSR7vO0ljZmRKk9SgUTS88JszEURxxq9iwc6V0RVmfCgyvd73I9ZtnszEBteFqEj8PkmknICeO8BnD1DN2YgBUJ6aBFkMoTXA2hiR6hQQsflql3UWD0t06siqDMcH7SQ/7r9vmkXoZ9Q@91BIwGckjy2Rjv9fR2ZJdm3Rmrf4O6GZjRALNvQPpNuCsnmoKEOpwpEfl4dXtiBK1DA2jYrQ8/9cQBcFw61bRCY5L@OwL4ggQQ3oeB3AQAJKAGECrdtEsVbIFSORnozLEwwpRBjArZdAQZCAkb0SPMClbfJbF6A13QuEcyfmUQSoZK21SRH3KeTInoEp2wFFiaK9sg8BhYEAW5tWbMVeOoDTcPXgc6lXJjrChF2E1hYANEWpuTUnqmpTbVfd2YTnjxx5xUWy2VSm9qoM0UgzoIzyE@AQAEYp/vh0Im@cUTKbjgCBVm4nUhYsSzD4un2u5ZxzcgDwQJ@oq4bPZTu7JQULtSgYZSt6jg0c/pS6krlmSqE16eSvhwKJS4MVQ/fhBYXF0PFUAV6zMXFp@BaRddTdEXB9ZRccXIhXAJdFCNGLgw9oxjoVwvdnrmYh5EaNoch9vafVDMsnxWL6VpMPpOcZwqfEaAz9BgAHccH4AlFymV0RiJC5RoKmmi0J0u/jr3eUdNSTYcIL@Qrmb87VEgTGaDicNRuKSVUXu6nSa9sgXYBg4FmN2yFzs/E89r5zXkren4bimHsSEkuN6BQkF64l@hYxgDUkMhZphiXapHIWRqUj0Y5JIaWw@F8XIOE5Ejkm3wkKnNqh0MK9Ibh8/MQENWhz1mzaxG@YSwViXikgnygwgO6djiUuMlD@o1ILRINQdxIKAZDt3IoBJRpIhFsKjS2pQkC7R@@5IRZj0YD1LwN6xJ/d7pT8EvAwJVH3wK5sH40OcvQu4ReizVtDVW8uMW1PHhNLnPPFj08TbbIdmgkoIMaAyUALabljThx8gNbnDtoMPwJ0TAbIcgP@3Tsr9QJGETcVocw8AJ5OnIVTNSLUMdch4G8oSmJU2pzAgNxgbMMSmKmlnnAu@tE0x7zAOiT4DQ1uQlSZRLducDOASHweTI5OyRSuoN4WgWl0eJDZYQOuynrSL@WSqOhgWp3kbygsaKssdpAVRwKgc6lENV2WBN0qQ5QWhmqfT42Aj46wijbsh2OoDZe5dosKtGoiWGm3LkVUpOMJowjFdDIMJQPytmmfqVaho5ETmwCamD4EtbBFPJZ5AU2qlZ3Uhvz6TsLOVDsjrfko60f6zRxm3aTJXVDMzoGWwYAZM1EgjP2jo4zU6BL92HYzmz1ExGo2jH00RQPKqhG2ah7S7m0N6qRETJJ8IkLkDVsdqHHAHPKfLTzfhM6OykripB/902kyyukD8t0GdGzycYAzgy5hnyDNfleMbujifk75A8@Ogd@MhTeMPl8iQyKCuTKaeGfKKq/kXMfaOduUMt1zSr7JmmeOEXkH71NlH6iT@TNBkoYnPJGX5cUE0jvVPi4flFwnScn5JY3II23e0ZfTr5JdG2GtwDqYXGVCXYytBhKxuN4FyiIpSos2VKukiilHMwglY@7AyWgNLsGE85BJ/QDCSBCuzC4iUMhoMdGRdKL5qwFBPrGAPTwlqKpPbW/QxOUmo7KZoLkYAIFgBOK069jBAeqAhoUHyGOBTdOIo6luN7h8IcgFAkrjMkSvOSW0kou89DNIXaEdkChJ9vb39isH1SPt8tCcmBbSU1tQMtpKfUeDCQ0xRbY9IUJQFJO/E@X2qFh9MucTS419uAVxDhu9N2N@u7O2mH18B3PBKGx1d5AkzErxaUpAIx@RMG8NPtaa3Jul5TuiTGRw9SoQZYYaNosHod7HP0oNdIxExiAHT6K4Xgc57RknLWzWEoSC4VWQ87nlVyrmcmstOV2q5VJSflsO59NZUW4reQKCvtM4PG4MqRxKLj4GA@Hw5gG5JweUiLjZEnMyg1JmZkpHnRPtpRWvpnPZmWlkWk2ZchVM5dWMm1RLGSUVErJNDJtSZZSqXuzxVNx@3VQ85vQT49mZsgLvSdPzWxWWckU5EKzUCjIqZVWWk7lVxQlt9LOiKKSk8R2Iy/l0/fmyZcNVCjGbz0aXUMDwYEYBY5Fup8BLKPnDbNtp60upbF1KhPrezjn5IRmMHTgrO75/HPo38MVu0Qz0Gk2Wdzgr56nA7iCgLiKRwpUJxpFSFrV8zwdyDyhxJW9hNVwPQvo6a3pTax2jdHNCp8fycF8I4m3iNzWB7bpK9mNJJH/Vb/dRpXR806R92Uc5aw29k6TN18TnFyNc8hyJ2gmsIcvQ/j4WuJMfHeCZgJ7@LIcH65BzkY3FTIL1EOWI2S4ZjkT11TADEAP0wph8q9zjsPyFDZvkdNJa2bw3Ege7gLhxoXQMSpaFnW8XMAU544eX6S067jwMeaRlDQRikF8aZPFWzCUX0UQ5JfPuOgJXjCEsM1Woj/sj1Gk/SjioPDyJU8vnDOCpNXlOrTKcW5dH18Qi2vQx0m5ceSsF9mYimqoY28PnNdrSquDCBj4mrTr4w/yIvEqdNdW/Y0ixWvQMsyRry3fpDjxe6ojTnytK83JTXIIVXNrIpBT23TXVyfCeLPka6r1Cz4DX3eWVP1Vlub0vsZ1VBoKkoA8Bn1w1wAtfle1aQeEX2IGvNHmeUBwh8yTkybjkNR4SYDFr2avZQh@RNR5gLi9NLBDHrvqYkLKIhYPRe9SuxuzDQMeuk2A3snU3RCuSPQabbrNAEAlZ3oWigJois/RmmBcJCcP6YGTfbNyMDltOZF8Q2kPYCyWbKg6uh8AixfyBNluNNR5oEAJXKR2nzPAiuxwAOPhVCKTkNzBNy4TQB/K5xyPd/YJEFpy985cN5sgfn9g9SGW8/xPP2pBJdytoq48ohGp56jryjXxR3tujTlR8YVus2uXq2cDTZWJMOR6CGVTxuVFWfMcs1FT7cfjXdnq4cDPqW5gULwBJ9zDazznlqINWor7nJ1IkRGRJ@fUma72WHMGNMFOTf/zxGiorxlyi8jAB@SqQpEsrGxeDcqQD0196jCIpXkJzZilZ@Nl8X530B/wO66EP1SNqom/@5po2tE1k4YtN1Tlnvq25MtBy4iblx0qLeYpNwN2XPAGznrG25p8yZ11dM4uOS@bpXY6iuU@54Fdd2FwSaPi5DU97mEJV7tiNGiS78Npafw@D8Tdm@Y55tNJ1ej2iBr2OIl4A/RpIi3uc4n7yKROEVaTGyOcHeh@PUthgqS2goApN6NRMY39rLeoOd5RY5rz42PnTPELhdmx@Q4bTpJZY9ck31kT5zOjVGZnr80DrRt6KbUna/FUy@ecK77dWfexawYoTRXFm5psAzP1nepQrqD66HYfg2M31ES2GrvuYe9xdty17XnLpI6Mcppw09BUG9uxNk9cTq8sjdPEPU50G0fFt7uEbZEmbHfjnmu2JDCafVyjnMNojxBpfHkQF2B9nJMw5hGtaVzjb64e0TWuFH6f3at9mpmrR8iouEYsoTZndh@t5kOcivtc6Dabjpcz89VvajP9nVWjydHAY3nZVjXDZkd0v48UoGDbNr/P5mI/1VRZj9Piht89O5qTKZMlnMncOXUpax1Dy@U7SRlucyt8YLVR8jvPx0o8T2JJ0sMSy1WADF1ynnNF/WXSunyIE2gFxMIVaJ/znn52lthyVtjmFxCGCritZHbhtsQ8xUwk@RzJvAqwmt1reeQ@f0BvMo@6bm9ijkihBv0OIxTy4OhbXMn@Iall7k@t9TiRdAftykOF8FXupaZA50X3O1XKUqL0lTEkUXy8gGprA2WgzJRP@40LBfcb3zPMeHymRKcYS86UchKIhxPKHtQnZ4D4qFxjv41v9woYWVOhkT@o3cyUdyYo4SaOqQ/AcYCOuxE7@sCcqNyJYZp@eD/luqbbso3WRCYx5GslUv5hHWpCp7cV@s0b2EAmQzbuE4ehsdED5UHni4EgeoBEakNT2LUKpOK7V3CTqj1zZoCmQvh9IinyGaseEzMmMzI0np2GylUv7TjOEz9O/qTmDeoJuFBI6lCA/gjv84g@S542DEP7mkoCsdpS6YiBFsfd4w9V1h2Nx9m8xMbTFzZOfjTa8yYueJfjDDCBejh27t8zWvZPTN0zzrszyX5Px@Wbcn9ojAmdNs0F4WYgxz2PN2kCRErkEyv3ti@ukBoNRZP5Y5jL3IevkEjfi89TQBxNl1bxcOWPr/WNl2GDU1LIHAGx1BYMU7pKT6HXe/R7uXUxsN3HXKChgb8ZwYkkLUvMiWeq0Ox1vE@sK/oUo76hw8CqL1sdBUcmGi6lO77zRK272jGTuDs9uaPwE0j3ycLxzATuauXjubFz9hxFkW@IakI0vl/kflaAhnOpjGz3ORPhq1ET6nPQe3hmbaqNN3HO88FGnUjOXOR5QPPTu0ZX7ypdixqH9zaveQBH9vnZsfsKAfnvyvYlbuMleTQe2HVtP3U1Q9MeQ12Uh1w6GkZ7Zr428QhOC6J@Fd6R3IAA5/HgrB303kQk6sbntZ2uMoAuyTb6hqnE6W0eqIbzPvw@T2q6M/GPmT1qaIaMe8Lv0diBBu7zMRibhvXgZEdHNvqmSY@6qQ1sutH8bZyORs2qqy3K6WOqXe3zDUmcOZWO0Wh21Yey1FDkvq5eJt2JG/5672DUEbtUcpXFN9A7oalAK2uUwOou@8OP8LEzr858SzczS78@sKzRwyJgcjOIN7HK1wPQMS99Z1F2RjB17rjjzt1Zds@ihLOGO5ebSGtGDTmuiKB/SHOnfSY2FzpyihYT56g3U@WmzPjWz75mvtLZCUIzd6pvrwv4z5qxmCfyth1JBkPB8PagY0ceZtxuC7QnvM1EWO3gsUmb9Q2D2Zpx7Ztdhg5H1p3HzP7XW228b8Eje@@KRyLprHHGlcHcKS1NNW1@Z/F2aiaWu4v2d6FGs4e3TvW0lDZflEDXQzpcz7Dw5AooC/GmpdhNnOZGOcs1Iy5ydKMD8jausTGwCzuzCHf3CczSQib7svjbPaUj447LXRU3X2r23e4NME9vGXgM4tcD2VZfD4y@MhPn9NaBx6B8JXfU5vZELbgIXeo62/P4Y6IRoNfdirjuqjYdIHAdsxsOZzNahZ8x5JqaSfcOst4/@@HTgJz9xiy@w9x9yZ4D5/IxXJ6Z1qR@6SzAzxV0ap9mSZ3nzHLO3mZx39TB9aBnDmznMTt12rDkny7uXZK/fa2CFIx/BKHLurLWnz2l7JsxBc3J6QnHznn69HtVMzrsfV5koGiBgEP1eg5jrUG/fCD3oQXoM5iV0n/kKiVOSMQtXriPwAhKmsVVXe3fP/nS78sw4nGfWCCuVOFxt@Qu3hPPvhZD/Hg2VXbvlfjQpY@aGoxhHoI6ePcAhLL@cNfywFoLdJWGPujH8YjwfV1E7t4uosiG@ZyPB1j49eark4jLCp1uk29zfUATsxUYuw1sbTR2zV3an8FhKlpMmC9k78ZwBwEbSlseaP1DXMZ7TLyqiedySKZvGLMGKwcj6GK@asQDvcSgt6E0cfnvUXnYM16Begb9lglStXeo4EL9lCCZHxmj7hpNWQOatR6V3BGhn9EpjMfKsqk0oO61sWu2/jUP@Ybcl2cRU8F5v/ZDg/YirgY1FOuCG5K4F/JuDraVIY0y5nMPV3Pi/WaTa9Q4jTbRaHwja8iLafBJyntyUYVu4KuH9gncXT3RscWbj6Lx/hXf1aG0@FkwexapD5WGoT0sU3SVL@rLlqrYyV1VHwzJj8VBL5s9inlBkkN8YJaMhgDOzhr9SrZpgX3ewIijlNDCynyUziZ1MoDgHZW1Y85JBPBTLedMnZ1wjWEE6dQGHZx193WzIB7nHeD4oG9YCUZw4bAcjUYiAR4JF1Y7OoC5UGSOAI8qc0sHNgMx3CdYtc3OztjSzbAoFqVbVmZCUWC1GseKFx2c3RyaZEvgkEc/W5Jr5aVQPB5aCp3rRSaGPHBFA01jJrg8AdtW6cHzOyYB02V@NgfdbolL/Ci23SUzBzCqbsHo/ESneXEc6fMDxfy0@jFu2frbv2w51h86ChS2p4K2DwRB4ydGT@ka1095uk7qIENltB6BOEAx1PhZ5vh6lYHGAsN4bvTBuGYnW8d55yi5Y2kFXg74MM/LBa9cnDLGA0t9Xnk8N97hEydhL5ZbKOgfBz2dXautftdOgBihs0gDa7yvG1wIpvctnCdqxdgOaym4YYaOmNHUqGYYl3QcAHPyt3/JD9DTQTPnAJCbPBnO8KWI58kkOrXebBoDyLWL5JNiGQ5IGIkMauIAFx0Yag7kH8HjV3SyHzgy7p5rp2T44fb16hGLb7IQGpHBc6gltR1eqh4@f3Mm1srfsV5S@U8/SkZuHMIJ38QLOVuIMRekdIuM5Q/OQvA4NMSEpaHAE/RO4alOv3fN6wNIJHMmw4N4Lo8Zhum0GrJNQqY4PG50jriG0U317B5w75FZE2JY5ZpWeuiMio69HtoL0W1oYPAaIdS81ZWXwgM@Nx4/6rMsJIhGAmRwcUModC4ND2tjlKUh@8y6yGQgVKWsCG@ckBraB@iV19y9k2n/ntbkhtIY0Oauq1QilS5TcZbq5dUKuUBeG2in4@zb82FKjJ8PVzZrSdsl6vn58Bsx9RaoblgQ60kSW97m3sbNUqIifv5syyMmCLehEt9yC2Ji6eZg52Dz6Lh6fHIEtXDrip8tfjLClTXIRXT6qWtoZAEF6ILS@ivkj/eG55HDbElmq2jyKxIJ@A/YEKhDayEuLHGnTzRNxH4g@qz4tuILvwvgyLS2ylyO2oFuAOsQmA2phoUfmGjHhTlxHVsUxGUqynhsQB5hcGPzDFlKpBJYGYgVB2I9klRsfmGfcr/HUOxBLPeT7elMEKSYl96ZF86LOJMEt7@VcpvQUf7m5eZY7i83wdxTbgD1fN04W9Wd3ZPDzclowGP0JKlbLmSdk2VcOGNL4@vlrvENOvzrRMR1hbLABIrAX53OjOy5NZT@tQLFcoRjs8cjE4dS/oXAmDGBMmU0ilcrcVqEw5QD1EFKWKypg29tdejLottH@9Dd8CJ6QmBL8FC7GU8IDuYgWSJL4OUWA7E65HKb3gEJcUdeh2y/@hNzWxwWDfvogc3b3Jyuyut1bAb/vl7JdaVqbMic7kyqsThLwU9T9A4U2IWNlHgfxZY4IYQlnnfByy9awYI8tS5kmvSjvbfOsS7opTXZRJM7DvSe0VeK7OPAoAPMrjDx9ItrnFKSucE3qtqmjKWhg9F6H83nuP0W4dvZOiqjdsZVM5Lvfp4b6NhRAZDP/NomnmADZuOn4LghJ05yw7EZ5HaVtB3CdmyEeFqCza5Um7ZLYCW0UcfRQFJiaZyCo0lEOrrOqpoNOkkLum9uQJCUkwQd/eDnP@I6E4LAkwlPZYwxIYCwdvmuDRnoSq9hxNT8wCMvERxhtn04Q6uL8ThQrqPqrgm/Itr0o1n@IutbA9xnVQndieJmoUiueLff03yAM6xpnSvJL3/wJ9yC1nkf3D913ENxDd5@z3lrg/v33RBJgrd/7r2l4O1n/O3bJFbZXbNBTvLOHMfcAzXAl8@EO2VCmeDaMaSyeLWNNf1m54DZtOKGddmTh75qQgmDPAcDM@C/HjDFFdUxgvMUxlU4xhM@ewMsAnwF/IHqDWo0lJ5i1cJoPKaYTGLGcVowQWcvlCFfbiNbMh8HaEMNlLBkLpvLSEnIZPzKRUiGBzq4@58jjESKIBMDV6pZ/tBo4vEuJthNWVPKuRLnjeSS/G1a@OBldAlgA3ygcMYgDp4I82JAWMWJFl6So1IEo2JHFpJCKNNaBmc10AbD5ACQCHrr7vlqUDcNh1TAx7oy7JPGNHIHQA00oYnLBAq3pOciigMijhstfU03x/G2fjzx5GugCX81CKcIdoRgRWEWs559y87753rNsfjGgPF@OYN1dXD/sxlm4DhnoSmGu/bHwtPWw7A07NmRbuAkwRbkloVTyVQ6KeUiPg4VHFSQX2zqnwElNG4QFk1FvTBMu7q@ufNi/@Dojh0tggxNg4VYqLIaPY8nYmc1zxHy8j1J1LWt5NGrtS2XlP5cjbdFIcR4b9R0NmelNp3TOamf8vMUd9OmgDsJSeJjEdNGhPgW7SK8i30cmvQBrvPt3HdSDUdubs9qq5VzPXgn@c@zbAsGE8vIXOA6t8myYGg6m5jFHfeUyDGaMrYT7kHAlDC2nOmdc@TvY@/5lrA8w8hjc1jueZQAmT0Ym0ZIzDmpAmVPJHlSZLOIZ8zNL8gaN6sSZnWcYDNwZ2ubPzfMKctdG87OoU2PSPt8Dsm1wGtzSJuEM59lIpt0Hs08uGMXIzb9sSElx4JQF3KnqY3AtWPswj3y6hm6SNimpvbDkYDuQEwffr0Lad9rj8gDk8tnQ@ad1rRRZxwmaLkkTGYUr2sBbs6JuVaXomS46WAAdDswTDaeRdtQXNch6FRsY8CnzxX2YtADuDY9DhXsLRTQsuIQGegZcrNyhqaKHEokeq1seBhJdJVhS@1AjxOOxEA0fSNJY5NPMtosAr2qMasEOC1ldmUoA1ZNehUtJg0jqwV6HReQzyey69neei0AyDBqI1LkMxehE921eogVX2ShmEeZRiQWSjA@knIMGtLuVZqISrD1Lu5rpqmPdlsllc1vSIV35m3V6iWwVNDNcBZ6jqca/FzzVda3fJSRz@SEqreUYRgNnRRrSCfwD12fXoUiwh0WJxNgjsGn1rQtMFcWyn1HKI3taE3Ju0LBk3OToqFQQGMpeO4XBiWQ4lHf2gUnqAjhdk82WXhA23xtlmD0Gj4P6zG7b0VYvILd9TXTWTRKcxrwoAAYsyBom1wqWa0Jo03XcLIMlYS@tt7CxyfVZGdSIlEDNyUSYUs4n7kO2hTOBEYCMEaFKEVCC/oF/BUxR9wwd8Ix0L1EyQbInhFDS20zgklO4coYyBegBZWaVZ747MCMBQynaqFQdGpjUtoXGPDF6gyBCGhnSHF3jAD0dY5xAtVQRgPUuqW0VJCXz14quq4AgYBnemiHXB4Ak1mRmGsiPza2VUspBHkWt51zoZDRSRu2m6EbDReclpIlmhor3YJa8@Ec9Zq2o9mMkv9tMpEs3YSXtPIoCbpmpBJe6palaHo5Gl3Sl8NLOmpbT57gjNrtEihz9QQMUIcAFF/SIiXgZ1D@ykt6aUleDS@1yqlligGvMES@gQjf2cnEzZJ8m1x6AspSDHwsLnTCSzaZQRMTCekW8octZCkZA565QXteZPgek19So1HMQ2Kpjhn4Lnl@FKVu8/woSZN3JWcskOz0nOY2pYp5NXHHYD8noONd9DqsLHZYzv7eugs8tmCbnhU2R/3jCb/EAxGMtnQptn/wJUyGPF6wOHIaZa4jZMLcDh0QcBgGIuJrTI5EQJj8@tdBKceY8DSXDhvRp1mxFA1lJRimw/g6@Az08OSyYAk35xvxK6a0U7mP8TO5nfhYO7g8OHgbOQ@zAgsF1/cFKSN8i98meNy1wlJzLvbDr2BwORkIJpelJyvJ5IcPH2DEAddZJVEB8cGvyFk8VDsLrzBWWVlZjuXyy7FnobovW5FwKhU5YqqaZOeqabda8DO69JWKcJBfT59SWjD8h3/G/Zz0HYf7giCOb/Ar4a7kbJCdr8jycjSTeqaXEikx9bd/vXgbuzmor/7t7/SSyiI@9vHx09tX6D6Sst8sLn6ztpbJxICQ3H3w/uBdtVrNbMSyB2fZp5m4uLj6H//D4mIqtZpKLtZsW6qFzi7fCikxIyT@9s9DBwev67YNhCjglWYSOPGeh5/Esll2yT7Bddlm@E/uTy2fW0Z3o/0Jbc/BeKVMwiYUyqZDR9@GZlfbIpMqT1f@88/3Pwb7wUoqeWrBsx/8GMzlg9wJDnhLu29XwUpwFcFyt8FRslwug3PlP/9biF95AXgwZLQKt0rWxZUbBSvxMkX5HKzkwCGlUpDu//WjHwWClWHwU1CSpOCI/urohiv/RHrC0JEUVvKCYTzDT47gNfRd41IkJSl17tanr7qxaj3vLuCGemWGz8@rd4@rmMMN5HgsXAVum3j93f/xd7/4u5/T3y/o9@/x4wq5xWcfNhhToAfGq1h8dqcedqfeDxNxuBJe6wjia9wpWTBfjtV5rjwWDvocU3Tw7swhiff@lXCBoGtMHOVQjb3Sx3VxHpTymf1nExU0fMAYWdC7mJOMR1IvcTbt51aG98JcWcC@Bi4Q/I694peuwz/83Ff0QY9X6Kfzm84hXBjPm/sgOzyFaxH@6B8u7xXvi@TjeBPI3WvxN5C@geBZ8KxW29bxr/ER/3Y/4d/HPv4dN/Hv8CP@HX/Cv8M@/h3Y@PeqgX/@mgkEV1dXg9HoIaiMDtM@5jqBXyJRd9485g0Ggr/ViwWgOdSi8dvbs8S3w2ip5PyDHlXy3vDiLshR7TYeX/22Eo2eUc7OKk4WV@OZ/dw@e1ar8FzTPVH/dhWwR1fPVsvGOv0S9Qpc8dq3lbPVSQyEpFZ59iyKDfYZIKjUzs4CwRuskzLeltlZb9iukemecvxMymVrceTAi2Eb2pONIClBSC6j4zPKfejIC4Eg6sAFrgoXyOPDl@//N/ydf/n@XxfoU0QYEkAOD0efRp@KmnglSpfS5Stjf/y/vz@EAHUoXhiW2BW7UguEKhOVE3EkjoZiz9iXWuBU4E/sgVMV20OxI@qiLkmj4QSq@f@9faP/at8AbAbE7A/FPiIW2/Ds7O@/AnxtSPsC/lRRFIeQyaF4Bf@ihiKezG7S89t65DxwxoQPCigQCSmUEEOJXCik1rI586MQC9XPz0K1UjBpn58nuWrFUpkSmVu9va3XN/c26vUkMttS9Fk0/gyuciW66jyeBiulp@fFONaxW9vB5OrT80o6ju5cFCowhX7Rr7zGGOFZWTwPwFjx9BR/p9dX19xFDnSdn9JV58Gnp0nudX3qXNdwJa/mIJhwMNBS/5H@W/v/Zf2/OmHhs1oEOP3mFga@dEXwLxK5ub25de6VSDjsvIRX4Q894B3j3NxW0ElAN@A6C0dqkdtb7gf3cGSVI6xgIqsVijwGhNYc5Kmeh0qMwbAq7KzInZ8PRTFSaoCPNzcvf6bFnUiJtr0sNXBBDoYS0nKEQLKZUinjuFfypVLecUu5XKm07EGJ8OI4AUix5WYJGb0UNCOYB87@YRFnZMimdSjsGEB/apowLJQK4ufPnle93lKteh39058/n0NLCuGul3IhCz5i/vNnaH6hCAwZ9wxnvbUAA0ApmRqj78q23O9b4U@qGTsP4c5A@zwUwfCUKCIwxmfZ1dVcplLJZcCdy0ciJWGJb5kJd6IFKXK7lBR4MWAwFwo6QVJ@JUK@tyEMZ8FV9rQCLG7jxW5ug0RtlslGwo2REvE8pEKB@7BMLpyPFpy/8mKEJSvLzPk7O0tHM8sry89qtbFmglKidCOXpdvyjVzECYbbUtMxKI27uOUnT9IFIEteLJ0H6vWN6nG1jl88wsVrlLnoSfImgAuTphU6o9mgbKF2hgWpnYdCxdIzXq/5LAuGSg5cPASSi@ULVN4gDDnVNh7fGAJWxBsIFqXlVHoxmR1@k9sUYai0jNfZ2Vk@lY8ug1xbLhRqtRr5rvIYbDloMmklHVwOmLTXaEVkLVyutXAKbRE8oe5YA1fWbUXTXEPd14alta7VlrIYCB7sVtc3j2OpVeiaUlvV9Vjq6GQtKOFrdvxOwWl8P9ysbuyfQISD3c3q0ebznTebJwfgj2Z94eodyMpAqSvXg8E1vtcVutZVW764kE2zbsI1bHMxh9eXX/7kyy//uy9/9rMvf/aTL3/2i199/4ufwO8v4fcz/vzZvylk8f6r7//5X3z50z8Dz38Pv38Hv7/@1fd/9CP@o/e/gd//6fP7G@fng@O/AOD6vV99//M//9X3v//H8PuXzu@P7/7@4K9n/37x4/k/jPfzv7gf5mf/Fn7/K8flwv7sT7kfPu/A/ymH@/0//vKH/zv//4/OHzr/7Msf/g3enJef/OzLj3/@5ce/8@XHP/3y43@a@vJH/7Mk@m9/AczzD3/1S/z/@V/9w7/7Jf7/L//qH/7qf/iH3/ufyPEn3PF//8t/w@9//zs/@fsf/4u//53v59x/cu/9@0f4f/@P4PP4fD4Gz2PK9bU@3/@g/Pwm1BinAjxAtrxZClSptZHCSiwgMtG5QRv5xT/78ke/C6z3hwAJb/89vME/f4Ggn3ovXkiUxqrx6Njzp4x9ToKOJz777IECyv8RfcGbfZ7ERr6i6/ur7//Fn6P3BOzv@jGI0l3YJQT2Uvspth0vY37Yn2Lr@/LLH33583/65Zd/8uWXv4cSNZ4pxKqxuPTAlBcAZh8Bh4C5x8ABoLSKq/@LbDGQAsfiKk7RBKTohw9A1kVwwZBiOZBNw1uwVsNBSeX8LFk5T55X@FWD90Sygj6J5HkSwxNJGJHU2TcwlsPfs2fL7Jt4nD/HfgGpQqghj1HoiiQY@C3zGZcoDuPhNwxkCvCGczBR6EGjPCgKQWtRVi6Xo4FhGcIIFF4xzpBV8jgjgGPIMuDFSDxOrJ4HpZwN1wgLxCxHD1l9uTzkEaPoUSEMDDOEXoeClBKi@fIGJFgebjDEhcijgQ/w/FCu5MvDCqL7jrIAOKJrkCRAlTF3w8p38F4mnAAfGG58B1nJl6PRSh58ylRUSi1WpzSlLBWOyh5lVG70h5E@PJ4@Y@wbQcoLfJALNcMcaLxHx9BPaa7nKYSfR5ed4tC/66TfMsaHah8SfbgfD3@K3hTfAQC88ThuPIMfVCMAPIPgIUcVpWThEeUYgHJRZybG8yD9JRqIUv1G6QXShzw87lqt@F4QHRZnaWkJXKsVIS3sw1CIWZdFuy9buC5DKl6RCbmCgN64j0dZOqDB0vLGMtwl@N9cpL24nBzLgaUQjpZDzE0jHk0bGSNIuXeLRmVZppxHCS4QHPtz9ZwW10CvzrBIIEwf5Yhg6ZuKacLzld1ZM4agQscEISbl@PR5xBmTvzOKxfJ3UmYlAE96H@D3QJwvU0A14Lc3E9hYkaCVm/gqNVxwgiaWC1QqzgIhkwKVo81jiHC8z6SUmGCgd99kVlKZbCabSudy2ZWUlMkVMrlsPg1CLydmUympkMkU8oWVW8rSMxAcseJyI7ta@Sd3rv/mn8y6ZvviFai8ZcMEi98GKsN4PJmiHJel7EppVIZ8kFegQnMVfIQxuonjvtDAOe1Du8EtT5CtwE0c2XQBLhZYCLAF8IIL0OLSCHPW63f2S87CJX4qii9eClIWGCESOAdG4NgC5qwrgJX3BCTOE4k7s7mxU0TnMZ7x3IN0oCp0tosbRfsGOzb4hsQ1pRlYdU4nVgIBWu05A8LWAvg5k7NaYDXphc7GtN7lH3ddtwxQ0384zJqsX/KgDZWfS/OCtmW0Fmf31H53DsSJ2cODPIr1j4Zhs9eADOKsLgdYg5ulGcYsgBV2cjCnlK@8M@O4bEqHxgH8cOf59rHvebxZXd8O5Nja/t7G1CPrAGXZ7ubWsfe6wkPdqFkPxbvN3d3pV@eBQ61Fll2JxUBGwg2fMbromVj61gWREvP74g4wMvRRyVW21GY4oM5C04eRX7kiD9swYlQSybrC6uW1s2Atn8mu5MTPOakgFVb2Br0BUoF1BvmdfaEoPGUnxcWShZLPbsp9OZZZKbVHLIc2kEFixlAY4V66gsTPhKh2YBuGcT38YAma9uoH8JhbC/dT4PC8gZ9zHJhsric80AudltrpghC8NlyAQEOWGfy@9oL4iv/q3@/R52mQ350QbQY4rh6qbSYGEjStlyrks/lCOpWP5QtAXCmXzcakVExaya8UxJgkSnkpl88WpFg@U0hnQFxCaLawEgiCWFHbyST0BpIg0FPVm2gnehUNbhuJbiUQ5LMi0AWHZejrIywoB@ue7yDPhHT@XITIAn72xe7TluFltSzgp8JF/BA3oJZZkwW3ttbFrS1BWMMXnMZcFwWhhS/ZvCiurAmCQiHrINtTgmDwOBAEYH3@Iopr64Iw4AjwGLwgdPFlM4d6rSCo@LJe3drCdC7wJYXxAeySh/AXzX1ZATAdX9JpUowF4aOHDuCqPKEM5XQTXzBNDNniIesQJgjP3fyIImA45HAcw7Zb1mpVEHb4S7WKIS@o4Fme1Zf4UqVLECx4AW4UhA44Opai6ILQACfypCA0wdUcyeCH1rnxxLTelwVhxAmEJBKEIUHLzUsBNC7HH5PZ3t6Wu/2W0uHXyOLPJmQNQtThYHOr8fx5o9NpWKPq5vNDDHnxYlu@GA2sRqfhRGvU4TIgDoRc9kbTF@Rxp16XtZkhLyFEnwqpj@oK5q0uf4Q8OVcHE@nVX0DICwgZzrg4Nrh6ANrAa60HzzW5QSHuRSH0HDYaQgkZtT8yFZxHwsZDO69iPblpGSV8H5YXQ@FQbHSWqpXIl/XCkRuxdIuB7TB9hAolZeRmdDYsizVQwqUSTmeFF3tPBZB7QnFRfhoeojsH4kxKZYRIcXF5GD6P1SNPhRSowUX8mpfRDrFQXHo6yAu5FaG4DE/hqZAG5zAshkTG4BaLnK3UngoriFR4@jQunEn4CjByPIMpgEtYKQiR0i2Qog99VWPQV@r1cPhakS8jEcwtKhWUbZwhj9zwnWYjKqtaaoeHsWGZZ4eNIiUsjKX0B9BXiXdwtvCk@AC/fsMxd4Aww6dikUoPmcljPpLJyCqKJxQo8PzgTNR7M/anpzOc/EqwYpx/KkvK5yIJ3MVeN9p1@iIJ@@CHRE3yFA@b0EFTd1cSKdF2MXCM6iZ9wZihDYoGfpyOzvbCOIYbw2F8FC@tFAKBiqN/4RnyxBZ@3NKwEvi5vH7JH8KPPrtex8qwn9hWcDtR0/Vb56c8E5tD/HivauhuwNEINIpeYmc/caLbclsp3cRP47d05BjPi@KJerXF5HIFXHIrTGkzOXJNxahXKuV6uaf0zP4IRjCkRFe8uNB7sjXGIfHkibv5HjpaKJ1Y0tF@DPW7S8PgMFBp4UH5tfLazaBYBNjbklKmj3YKQaHUfqqXB5TBA8XCcyI7@9CXK3ggo9n9cL6JcOtAyJvbeMViUDo3Ezs2J4639Z/yc4P5cQLqZfG21Cmfof9nvK3GBaEWj599roFqXRZLo6BctgcN/pUlsQG6f640BD9pJVPSgDT8cM4SbdGTS13WKDe@HZassjmwlBKBf9agX6wn6tAez1KpVCwlFmIpCXo/6BUhGH4r8J6BnwQ/CJdWaouLYS0sMCbExKGYkGKSIsX6xqYORBWLRaQtVAq9wlOORFPLWrhlMHk1TnUEjbGEGQCB0GWmGuuGIdahImscPBL9@DQXZ5ksi5Q@AgmspXArsRZ5mim1wmusHgEP6MLhl2K5TMlfpeFIqV1m4W8jpfBipGwrH/kgg4poLgIx@XBjyR70zsTFnBS7idfjt5ps95eklVTxbLB0FpegdOLnzqrwviLUgNS3ARiZ@CftQTsogZ/bULk@MdYIxn5mCRRATYGKkQqpkgMSMB2pAfQL47ck@Za1cCi0kgqFIqESQC2CN0mfyA2JiBBIsNATCeQW9NVFoZCC8LGwuZMDPqTKSYHgbaCl2ibLFALBm8Dtze1qxad6vmSjkRyNu69PGOtEYXydpIXGRD3IFskVT1RocqFarnYOqyUHurpOA@Gkb3MAO@cHI@PJxa9d24yuVr7lz3Nc8oY0QRdtGNoZqzkLsKl0IGjfBDgJad9AcjVaSZ4HBAGboLNSFc5nI84A/bsgmfNl6zfud3eLr3CUyMJykTeus1rkuz1Vu8mn4xW@TY8Fv4Pi446YSvK7IDDT7S2R1dmPEgjqhu87930QZSC9s1kBh/MKM48K3658m//21cn@yf4WeyYW88U8p835s1hMCkmhVfYMFEj1cBMy@ZkZWek7/UUpWDRD6Uwo7R8WnJeDw3LGK5ZUqcSl1RR7CszHiiAu2lIuLn6ucE6qUEAuBSFffvePM8PVPLynQCsrMml1NbWcqpBHKgseqdRKJPjl@3@Nh5xTK65Lyq0Ea0GeVgYAanxraUoKVpKOt7QiRYJ2nL9BNrJBu/A5mBLzgWD@1YfPjK3CqKPS6nTUFLmSLmss3fCL3dy9osm7frert/BfuT1bXb2l6Y5bx4G321sePPFPj/E1B2YcXvu2/m29@F18lf@vwm1xfZ8XU8hlBRYJfgA5ZNu4VlYI4kxWCEZoIQYUZKYSBfEL/deZx5pS6bZUM03zW9OEQcayTn@KvYx/4/dl27ZXl71XBQNZtiIxGJQkk19@949Sqdz/8x/@4DzyGqRwoVDISangr@9eyeWFAFteqLIQt9DHu3C0xOsdyAtNfBsT566WF@IbR/vrLzePsQ9XdPxmPFvf30tgEH7WfHyisqkpsqWNnO@ajxAKu/7j9QNmWOxk44DinNJZWvKlKSonlaWdVtH5AlnsikmJNK7aZpNiJillmZQviivFVI7JIBNttJ3huJYwKqNirRvmiA8mw@sRirxQRRgM21VhuG8rRfb8YJdikNBZXtjYfLXP9vd23yVcX@5/vL1zxI72t45Pq4ebUI5Xm0dMqB6xnSOBne4cb@@fHLPq3jsGwYfVveOdzSNEkAygPEUllxPMG9mxVXtkJ1EDtml4N@FtG81LpT/pL1umnETT0pPeOn5sSsEvtUz6D3QVxo7@keNRdYHrjQzRy62WFcBDvGqTLeBYcWEZNBA8Q9wV7RWWHbz9JFrZRdbM7IVWWFPc09OrK0wTnT@mZXrpQ7a4uHiuC15n5C@GN3D1e@HxD/Ab52nn/eZCOJdhyzBITWUi45C9/YMF0X1bOD08XpC8sMONhZT3srO1kPZeNuEt471tnW4sZL23terLhdw42t76wor3trG5vpD33oBJFwpjnHsbC5IYcIl1BUriAn19Nby1s7vJlgEoUpoIxYlDdEx5AyHCoNhxiypIcra8fN01YjT@aYymoFvKQ9Au@ATUAqqWZ0jXWowtGybcQGkFYIgW8MYgstVpxhysaJwNOq/ATWABC7SABQJ4@oY9wrHFMkvxz8u3@QaSMDfWGWPCiU0ndr@x2SoODyrADDGy9kYntyGG4nyGGT9Gz1GG2zS52qbt6AQqQU4FS4hE8Ljn3snuLk/MJI04LBAk/6a9MAOnYQI2KCLcsejgyyuHVwvVBdJqwdFw8FPRgduJ2gxM1yaSAsq5sNAEBJPUvZK1GEMNL4abFhAvvvBjJAAMweAWwcXPuYbDTSxrR@k3KUMRJObm/hYvIW57KLPJWo4wTJQoRcH8gMrnz8x9O@9PvlqTr3qI43aQ82xxfDynZYSNoN@Ce8CYIMiYAsVcQI6JRiE2FIfCfOVaAKLDj9tecHNZgYTEEHvyhPKxCm@FECWB8aKUIosjCCJwCEbkQ2Re1hYpu5GF5DLuPKJ9SGRQGPsRbum5MfLsxoBknc7oVK16rdCrzgUdRs6lKYHsBLVbWNfgTqfq8I7iETg5xhrQTGLMDZRyGIijyRhTYqwN3lMyta7qwLmKNZaJLitAY6Ta39vgNcSNJJE/96ASg9wrUoWBsHiCzZcYfWGhYSnyZcmFAnlIUMC3yDRhJASHuz/e4QZFW@btBdkSYz8m5s5W0eUjHhvYweE0IivateC84hSXPCtjoDv4HWTYfsuAnrMkRxaNOhAelzlgm5Nw8TiHu3X58oFCbE6XYvGrS4FieW4pNh9ZjN@sFNCtjVkESgEiPgx4owBNt8naTM1CAX0hoaDS/DAU0IGOeQna@ASCR8SHLnccP/718aGTLk43ZWi3UINcKvAok6/NydfW5Cs2X/CR2eoqS2VgRNVAl5QDF9o3YHlwtLisnIzYnnylyaYyU9w4bU8C8xSA51BUcjBkwLvCGCVIwsYP1Mg9/ExamVW36jt7m8eToYgvYdedjHf7hq5RGpFJMCdDGG6H8SXi5SjcRiJwfTN8wNOIET3rR8eHm9VXMchfhK2OW8C0DgA3pyVMlODWTQF8daUJ/XErxsJHVbYcYU8wZzHmTFzgy6OT0AxbAVRzU2wNzBQlJXIQ732yJQWxRQZmJCWEWTjCPp@fQ5cqrjCpZ35O99L6SrrFRukVVHY5Hk8HcaS8K2D2eNPkygZCtrhh0uLMxC5EkWWsNOsrXdC4h6J1Fz@V6xb7NuoW3VPYpkGDMrvE8NA7yhbHZg30i5Oqzf1aJPWNyAfoi80Y/LA7pwnKKOnnyJ4U6ipYPC8t5Wvz8pBGO5mXOM/LKiV6Nw@/diZ1YbgUmDppT6Z/DLNvyngY3Qncp6ngA/SyAgE@meOzABc28NNU/UiRLPegTKnX0SJxvR62Fa0NzGoMrCZ0@agu2w4YXhia4IHUkNAxGeiQB/WnyQD@DXu09wq9zhRCtM0C3mhvMkwpBgJezuy@YlKufNnAOTv8bLs/QRhgT7xDteKhTl@OI0VHK96SsT24yM4mjHZxHAO7G5vhDeL5rq/HpjPCPLaZEYa2GWdFcY0NzAi7GPRm5QAEw5wQ57jwjBDd2J8Vgdu8GgfUznwEPPMTuFYLR2ZXPbSryRr3GS0j@h9bA8WxwLWz72NBUC4dDvTVdXBDAaZtqvjtj2lEnsECiBkeRny2Ezy2iow5SbabqjqN3sXkIKLDv/R5CzYsNruA9RsplY/EfAh9GFvc/vE8nMyHFHI4A0mQHRHvu9OstocaWXAa7zh@Ak1/6C0Y3o0jGOY98Bg6hsXKd4EX0GqbF@Ix84wmN0ZXvMs45I8LAFj90oR9u3nQbiGkiJ@gv2ny8a9NPu5LH9vkD0q6zM4m81GL@t6L4DEuo9vAf1BCbq4nU4t8VYn9XKMol3PYF@0Q@ZLh9kcmk/XQOBLI4ym3KIQePR4pJBCXH9FXyBeqPsc6wqzY4/5nuczikheHS7xxa6B5aV/mA2g5pV5Hk8P1OtmarNdxZqleF3gK1PFih@fvdJ3GxsMSoKXWDQoNC3FZiAnxePVofWcnrupCjH9OoSzYfcNS6mgyTojhondZIIFVR5iuopllwdmvKNuMYgvz06j60oACPpwIAfFUdnRKZGxL@OHkmv4iGY8okjGV2Ni@6SNSO6TU0JTDfSlZ3FCgm9A62bJD44CWoqKg4R@KQH4w2mT0ZcLWCE7pO1ng6do002ejhReeJXrU0c@pazSVsqvSqJpm@wTX9pFwx1SR09pxqgcRjDmVc59wQB@OY2QHr6U4ehZNDyWEsQ1UJ2MJp6Q@fncVNG46ZtyhTdpDcvIbc@cmbZzGnMrqWLAYJhb@TEBzSVABB4YJd89kErg9o0ngRrNJ6OWKOnCjzSSM0XYcjvkkcJEBJXgCewtje609eaj2Bjhx4zfK4Why42xhl48loV6fAielH6coQiQ0NHwddvBGokJRgKLbZKxp2mATws@y2RSpBe4KWbIwjtn0qQ6zkM60AhWJ/RYqyaeIoWi2ndxA3JjABK6EUFypWIPBp493XBGD6vOUn8FnPRERlCTmxR/3Vz6bT@WJ4QVSBAYPPDPjCHyWyf@tVlLuI0VPBRnXmB@KK24z8o1bjedm3I/BVdQigXtGUv@/GSf5q@S/0KHS//eDojtDn3/kocw9Q5ivHq38FocF/1Wh/68K/Q9Q6H9r2vwclXwa5d0WP6WuP6iGf736RTJvBN2G1bnCqbfUD9HDfkuKwMpX6QFurs@k@3SBh/tnF03K363/wF468OvkcSt3umVUq9XjnmQdPq92qt3qIZrXWhN3o6cXmbWN67Xna63qxkbnRWd9T3mdr2Z2zZdv8@@etz99VEB7395/8f6TZja7gbeH5vWpcnCdVvJ2dTD4uLM96m@vnfTWj7LvVq7FTS3bXlM@bmj2xqvjty@Pn2ePotcfXxy8@NQTe/ZBW5QLvfT2q9yb9dGpHsheqSetrV11v3fU2jxJ9XY31Hdb0XVx96jwWhJ3N6/fp9evo1kxuWO@3H9@eHLR2HyvHe7svmutfzTk3MfLa3Mn2Sq01y8O3wT206@l7Y/7@53NVOH5dvJ6o222xNS2ZmUv3h4erJ282@6@lDd7W9mTwtuL0UGu@/r1VX8v2smc5gav7ExUr75@nXqpP7@62jwMNGTj2Eorp8Zryby@PjAKvRXl5d52p/fakvTkfvZN9Kh3fL2xuaZ9XBmmT96dvr7OHL0bvHr94v2@qB4dNTblnNlopY4ujjOBZi@9E7062TzJy89bp697Vzvb2XcbyVddZa/aOtAun3e23xtHB7s71bQ90KXd9Svt3fPuxavLjfUdzTi41PRqJpnVjlvv9vcDJy/Uxoay/dZ@Ub3ovktm1y4z76It8/nxxafu5Yu1o5P9fGp4MBKNdfuwsd0ebhzmUvlkU/t4@KltvJJOXkdzVxcvUuq76qd@IP1plC3sau@Unv4i2uy8H37UktETSVp/v/Pp3buj7SurUdVPPr7ZOrywXrX0fXtfPHzx8lVDu8z3L8z3@tGR1BSfK5evoqIcGJ5s21BHyrGcXTnu7b42hxvGx8Od93buU/Tq9DKtbFwevql@PBQb17r5Vrd21d662NqXq2@M/uZg@LxZuDq53NZ2P@7b7wKvNqVsdsto22vtN5nC2@TzaPvy@ds16Wgo7umH7UzO2nvz@lRVN7tvTz4dNrNbb8x8r693Xn866W1GN3eH3U9KXmxoR@8u9cBJ9ujwIHWtv1R7/a3tw1e5/r64@@agtT2Sqq8V6VpfWR9lN4ZWLn268dZ6d7mtm8l36sfBgahcRVvvzH7mtdpoN9@ozd7LwNGL7snewZvrnWzOet7T1bWDvLi3u72@12llXo52Xg02dxsXrec7b5W35nHuMrW5dprbeHuU7h9fvuwXmle99EE@eqz1@p2TaODFoDtYOTi1Pr4Zvs9Uew0lfai9M0YrUm/9hZkavqlu7n/qXB6Yxp60lRolT3aNS038dHz9advOVUfR/PCk3zP6x9IwK70OpK8/mf0X5ovXR/trL/bfv5AzqnoqXxy9aYnpk3xS7VrpnVzuubS51e597BUU6dPGq7Sc7nWj9u5lsrXeOnlzeqld9F72LpqBfMFuru28H8jGZiMlie/W2ptZZXdt91hSTjovjzIbe@LB29bBycfhcWv97eDkzb4qbl68KOx2Mm8P3xRerrw/to/lU@PtS2svMMynDVvKFbLX6aNCfr9rHaVPLwr99y8vcmvaaUN6sZPqKVuq9TY/yl@an7rXnesjRWx0nm98lA/bmyBJTw5EOTu43BseBdJvjntXK@Za9N1l8@VbXdLyp@pK8vjjReGy2315vdHMnFY/fZSzzy@UwtFWsqFtZZ9HD9dfH1x0Nk4/5TMtcW33jfx2uNntvwu83lY3Lgqnl/vDkfR662jUq4q6lr06Os1eHRtrR6fbR/nuq4bVbmxfdEE29EYnF9eDq21lpTu8zr/sXryRxd23@XXdzhyIgRfKTq91ePzybTXaTimF/tX@uz3zNH86zL7KG6cFYz@vvqy2nw9f77c3xRVTPT0enmx2k2vrai8PMuVAO7HW919vvz99YYqBlJ5b@7RuZFc@Rq@G73KnyYPo7uBd8zjVO7Ws7beqtfX26uDty6PqTnSnMXp@cCnvv9vMHu2tr9svoltqThltp6/t6npaaxsBu7c23BtaZiH9/nK3Az2B0Sq0nh@nT3W7Wm1f7@SPNqvV53Zj54U8HD5vr0Afgdfm6RujHPg1N50Y4FYT@UPm1lcCPbvTMIYgL/nRxwCdXQvQ2bUAP61G27X5JudfJ5cDx/5DGnhEz7FnP2iAssZaBioPCbbj2TfGz5vEWM@A6Cq6moZJT0TrHEdp4YBPgzvNV@HhSvpkqjI0NUPFL0fhVyxwTGqNv26YCOzrrDfC8WZf6fGjIyp@/MkxR0wfvuDf2CJzqIGFZpO5H5ZNkLFd7zOzH0CBMPVOnKwrd1g83mxrcscGh9Yi14fAkWf9H1PQVBknPzAJabcuS2LW2ZpKH4PEzB3jN6v2njP80h5ug3VHHDIoEyMySoOTVGSYRsGPT9rqlaKN6DspSisR4Ds@H7UL0u@HO8gn/cgk7NTeUFA3FGtqA6jJI7orrcnlZ2gY6Nly0lliRWWoLlsNtY@fNq/zExx1nqK7582c3HtIJ5@dBVquGKFmQ8aUubMnD/FtKhZSjHaxjw8g4n46SBFUVHe34fKySShp3xXjLz7My@Z83Gqv89tCPYG7pSoTeA2g1QBoRQvSd9bsv7Fpk6MHVArwxfrNtzvHdedjOnyL4cSprzk7Ln1ULrlvZomXwJd/J@d3t2XiDgPIPk47clvkUNQrg/OyQPsecXsk1DaOsMe7LRPANbTTALGZtBvlLFPjOwhF2rrnEtyL84RzwhNfrp6MCbrgbKjweOCR8fgGTQ5yt7yIuG0pCgHQbk73mMrUZr/fMu/NqZmGJuuX6CrxrbIwXrCavsqiz4T4yoFTWV5ZnP2T/LwflBuiettgxxkVLK9aCMDZEOtW84mOzZn222McXsNe0jg/hml4oy5NM5rhcfCyu@WGly3ipsThp5Lax5nENu6sNawRTwinZ8KlEoDgPh2SCYru7lb1lbo8pgaio009vlwA35ZcLzSzoIzzGWP355YntUjsQDuAZmeVbwZCqDMvWzWe1HxZCPSO@AszEXVMHHcLETiTy6xvmECEtsNx0I0Rj/DdqXeownd6eVzEOJ3OxBr8s6f@lyLfuIsNCg/0MxQhEWzGOEKfypyXaQSteE0HkxqzHlUU7uDGKlSJF5kKI3z0Z2o0OlFPPuRnKtJNYlGidnhGKIghr0QO6R3aEwztiYPa4FtxWZvv4OK0DkyRaBUS@vzZazDw6nHjgXu2FFiCnx01mI0MzjmTt2WHoCX33W2EnptCxkTxpOrt3b30dLAWBuDGtakOFS0MArOOHwkyGXg5W5ZMkzsIwtu@BN5Y2ZR3R14tLoYh1hnBJfM19oSFpdXV8Eo8TF7f5CMRrzE60VO@6L7IIKQrFRZOLYfTbuQMRgaU6UkEmdkIUhxBZjksuQhSDgIpCxi4ikFIvmF5zrWTiPM@xB7e2iQMfmpoRurLqahUW13N4x5Pn@dU5NTsrC@noymIzFEvRCdDOFoe4POvTZYIkKdTvn7EhyITTQMKnnR0MmCc6lSAl6g/zUxtZuf0W1Ne3HMabudD0fGLp4p1lsfyIqfyTekmA7fZtxxP/OqcSd@eG/txll5GNgcdgZokpNZV8NBUjH970Om0gH6lqV7RdziCIFAMEBFcPGqMXdzX1zW@vrND4DZN8PEyx5gUY3kYhoBEAYmRh8ggQogGaqfe7JkeHHTF@Qjf8c07MEpkD1ec8fwA1BOq/W5KJMY4@XCFG/A5336jPoTTNwwR6rs7a/h4s3mIO2Z39p5DFS5gOWJsfHeLucgxekVcl3X@PRq1r0IWQLbxAY1TVl5Vk@mjp5u@g81F7sBPY@cRqXQIwXhkRzskvlD7ddVwsHFSunyk9ImO9Hk0DyAfKcE4g10rTNaQHCP@Wec8/4oaHXqj2EQqcHgRnQwihZBmx4fVvaOt/cNXRLmDenX3YLuKmGGA2ZStFqPv/GAD0XVF452qR88Adr8goXmZ5Ib7URoVbXEQLP9gJCceANYppE6@0znC8nKmvwPPvWdFIIniQYNSUW8p5gzcuHfVA3MKY89AyGuR59rpCp08zeoJqcO72xO6crSCko5oaSi2HuoDY9N3j2Sdy5Oki28NRpn00UhquahHdYhfLP6VvHSKPp2NfGQPTFwdVlqCn/xys6nYZMxhTH1AqWhtSsSRLD5Cgc/s0o/lBz@b4vW9Dg76cih1uqKn947V3EllEbRHTrsfpOP6FCSOxdWRbly1ktQiJ2X@Je8J1VGdVBnnJcZTu@CpXUBqXOCyi2mFTK2dXUwoYrPIo7rkueC6sauZcfXE20pONdeGRm930egSzYVwqUMVhtVEFkaM0YSse@JW2RO3FY9b4mzl7n6lzCHspEbmdDjj/tMZMLdaQLbwnbkNOrlCo6@BhfXPX3TlGl@op@QHndwhBsETp9RBnXbhXPGJZ6jmcgZiAmlIp2XOnORq1Kl4@MIOQhZ38xPx6Rp0CtOZFVB1kBbjw2lOWUmVNGxnoOjzRLHq9MJWy23kBDnuzKzW9IEuBEJffuBwfCqBH@PjCeXRSV8dLRNq5JCxzkoBXFeNxyFChM9rkE4D4hbLQNlT@7OLkb9bDKdwrk6m8hMwKOoct8RFAYJ@hnEP@LqJl2aW21cO9zAcRo74CiaWnBMU7onekwOWltJp3/Hf/dM9lsuNTwejNTeWSYnjI8do143lCoEfNE82nk/g/IgNx6lQZCvkGRy6gy6oaBo0Yv5oqdj1Y974sHjIH6OSp1wt8xGs7Yhjp2uwWW9g4xQlk3GEjkcrpaGUCCyAUKQ5YOeDqG7nDYCdgWzJel/hZyxRkDsru5ggRUQdVrGgXA1oGbhtDCV@D63q2QNL4RPA4NMymrRJEnFQPKjpQY92I8VQYbhSLDQDoPadg/4LJHMcduCiocKZwPV0hUPF5Q1OQkckUIvGSRZORuqWkXp86sVxpUhdOd4VKZfHuxJ1ae63lTEDRF6HVYjG3B1YcAh8p5uh8fiy84E5t0l6wGPRP2tq8G4nwwen7jjcQcP7mLsjf7U2YzKGuKvp74OGziYmQkVlqkXcM3AkAdwjUE13HoID0WNYo@6JcPHRKFIQxi8tlc@FM5IRpEVQL0VdioVch7t0HFt@FLzgfV2e@LkMrS/i7AwYOQfmvOORDgSyfIRDOGcjpyGwfXKIoR8H5II31OXkeP/BEHF4591QfBOHuKNwdEeccQEi4ONaUrt4/vmZtNmlcNooJcqPpE3nlIIivrY8G4wX2QHD0vnAIFMkj5Y98zgc7ORgfO7NBaTc04TUfZmfSO2xmXeSuwM0QYlHZt0jxK0zVzcLKUTuGVcKX6RyttU4aqavfriSBJXoMALxLLV7Z6rCoYErFXjuGr4YXGd247iShEKcQ793RY4D5TmWU@5xYFege9Oc43O9swrKOdktqltMqkH6wrummtQ1TpbVaRb@ssalu4Vd8RXWPWU8UVgnklvOu/YddHC0NeOa21/ADkVwTi4L37Ri7JsWLoY4Pv4@yqXGLPk3edbZ1yC/LY9bpFc@L690aNZ74W3VWTtE0e7nd4yHeEW3keMnvqkLkBDc0Evu5noea2HBUWdA6ZmIl4o4084eO7so2m2Q17RVH@337qZcTGOOISxl9h3HQ13QJ8WaAHbBPpOcxwxEPNi2CiX1wfq4yJHME43U5Q4MiEad/qw8MRs8PkA9lxH9WBzZ6TuifG98kil3czHCMN5NzsbhRnG6@3H7L/kzMpqbESQHrRE5fZ23ZsRNItz@piujY93NdDQ30LvMFNw@OoqYo79lRVcPCJtjfcEbHfDxgF83cBRtVxnEiS1Q4GFszI9GxxikPhd@bGHkI1/gw6N5EJMsgPijkakJv0DiOUz5hkWmbxBzN5tUO0RRk9fJZL6pImkixMPOi/HEPENkyVQclwG5MyrdKdUEOkaHnGk2rsSNf5Aqi/bXaZzqt/6BFb@Mhccly/E4y8TDwe5uB0Kh9kxN4Sd3pN16dX/HM23Fuv2@WUwmFdtALzthWJ3ktXqpJjlg4MgxWxVXBtjO0UgVD6lvnkBXhgan@gl2pPDNCqj3olr2gYaTyiDyASOhBSwdgNtt0Hj1poJftelf4/4BB4Gd8GcWgmUb9HBDZyPDaIxzLzsnc3gGYpR3GzLfAcIMGgnIQLIp921lpCQxYrKhwa0noxXtJAzJk1jC5L6u7ELsI2gSSuJCvpIDG76M0cnpqVTJ1l0gjnNHFNLHT8LT7hGcQ@jjvkjWMKBuvP2pziCBjGEaujZiOpoA6ACmK4QGqQJJIeddQzFpx62zqENbHhQaR2TEQo6Eve30cBQP@@9EAsKykQD/nHERz3fYBrKLpdDeVIo@sadlak8Gb5iTmyj4OH/Sr4nGuR7ep@Ft8UgmfXEN/TH7Pmbt8SD7X0D2eTs/kkmcHjU1ecSEa5nsl7P1zIqYK@JYS@3oxIbYWtCIjk9jV4YmfhQYNwZgP@7G1ZQrRWNprMY3qj0AwKP@AIoUCJqW3OnJLmA4XWSYjM9GF42vJ070j4MMQ5v0aeO5CTYeUePJNMakMTY6weX0KkhMx9vpF5QISC24PcUtz4ZhsiI4Wkpj0KHOAM9luTHwdJQca2AEOVIJNyJP4VmEJ2SdrGJDO8bGX/bsV@F@IkNlZ9DMa8xdoBBKASoFNP0yz33JjY89B4L5VnSgw@arGtAjLLO6MxjlswQAjX1YmMPZfN6TFs9dkJaxs4@zNpQg31zshmARuTHBSGnunpJl5ttTAiIB7U0hY5IJrGTSnRkJVfHzzu7LWoiH0qxRmLvHU0S811v2yOHuX2jz3SerZBOMkUFRImek5O6ql0rs1gXEPSCo4eDOknjI3TmAGqaFazPjHSlAesEdhd2H1peB9AOQVHHIZtgv@YrBN3jX@GyXo4JMB0s1dw0L/MtiyaUG/xq8V//jxawnvDYXqOCL9G35G@ao00KTL8TQKomzwDSRV@y8HB4h7uC4nC4@zPmBPCa5wZlNpEnTmDehyjPK51xBWKDOGacuJcaGrIOz73z4FGMj5xXt8Qe40W0xNipLJc8yt6IPejc4GInxKAMzhsC3TAFpXwrg3RnRWTxxr3VDL0FiHQV5gAQFep25/ji1cSPGmHRbopSb9I03LuJBj7jL@zP3Yp3riK94BkMR@q/xbqL4TUuI8fRwyYAckutI1WLj1DgRvVwPR8ZleBgbgehgeB6p4ow60O1Mzv@/7X1bcxtJlt6z8CtSUHcDEO7UpUlCRd3IntZaEmWKmp4Jio3BpUBWC0RhUIAINMUJr@8OOxyx3vGsd7yX8GXWDvvVdux6I@wHv/f8h/0F@w/G5zsnMyurUCCp7p6esKM1MU1U5smT98xzTp4Lfy6cLPZRot9p9AEDOWy7g3fHNsauaDyQqfbcIwapvfAgwxP/XyB4ZVuwAxnAbyoCrFYBSByqMsQu5/Mw09E3L5eRT0xdMn823gSXbcov5WP2GL@Ud/Gfx07yeBza80p7UTJ6KVSivbjJQ2DVU86XusvN@wb9XWpvqr9L42H7u2I8bH@Xx/Nr9ddKjH/EHaErhv@AxwHLfp84aoK2iSKnuK@Q2IhvqO0fp0vPxgi4lCrNcTKWS4fjcRjBPXt2C6TOjEZwvpNOdd6XOjbpNzHIdREfNdcbtPUQ8SDKyRafhKAXi/wbQTnl/iJ6ciiybX1HcwIwb7BE335WU99UQUlfJW6SORJt/1CVnKlCThDZ9ob1iz3lVNWyDeeOCg@muLDtfUnJp4PD6TqrL1JrTBEMVEllFZmB7kC5dBGkZRfRo67Px2QpjLrKLGUmEaW1dqWhhPjYyT8RLimmuvPOW1ObT2darg49YflYK@@dl80Cl8lgSW@hbG5pYsWeDFja9lgUsdULLZ2C2ROR8NPjSTg7OlZwFAUaELCiUj4IQd2DuiSqHpFYZ/BVs2nU4opx9638uK5ejRUx@Ww/j5377IV6DMK/u4AsWWQBReea0BpW164Z2ulaLNK@xie9BT4UQZ9IHOLqec6cBmxjPVATnkESR9Xv8XLKqNhcYtWmpUDynekUsQFAWQfSBXQ/LjbGM0xcEBSA8fHFxMo1C5rdWFnGTmu5dW5zn9JSyWptI7ORbIaabmTXh6ivcUHjRIqYlt1Qc1A7WrPt/xbmz9Yqr9fE91@yNKlSsyorDOcTkwvlaCJ2YJp3ggDD8KwhK5U4cEL5PJyAN1xUMjGfQh7Hu6tzSrwXs8qAK9d0c46Jn30LRaPM0vzidtyhqWLTASCiFjBpJW9neC9DcDuUfsbsqC0sDHDEpBz8zkozwh5emU3h5ZGYhD3f70cgWTtYK9zOIswb9HY1r4T9oHMEDpE4dXP0muawPJq5xeOgJ1YZj1@gKRP/p7NgIsw2WlOjuWS9H1oKj4/93huGRQinGHs1GFVp2EbTajhQ0U9nnQlEDuFElQtRTp/xctPsaU2cNB2lD6hWAphXnrdMhDjAID/hCjK1rIy8DqIac@axsg4iihQiHc9Dy4wwtq7sB1KTmqLzygpk6HoeagvdIGI8DvtdUYPZEGdxOK4hDydhsrPuFwjL7nVPnBgmuul8JIDkYE3mOhi1GsrEYijyNa5vYjlpLgffWIJGVSuAqwJteSxnfO2g0VAmxi3xvMNGQbH8grJZfl7EeosMzAC6FhNfsxAo0yhVuJJltHwVL2MdhaOqi1nAlhETHMBKV50/7zuaPwUCaISzhw4YmL9DwtjrQFjJTdfcJ@107iUWsu4KnQMns@G0M/LDWTRc/LYXQu4axyzVtDMlLfjzx/ozSY6DDRPurI5gAOpJfZfV3aCbAEadDu@1p5vIye/rowYTdxLqe1YNtRlMVDFxh/BMVNxH3lOdh8vR6ASkcuAyAZIeqAlM2carImoDdHSyudhoWuNyRsGu05vO@BA9DqFcAZ3SGeRB0PGYwESMpwQHNvoC5OHYn0hltNoW4UyZ@5nWa@zqkw7I2NdmQJXqq4/x42xGt7Du5SIhPMDtoILK4ZHvlKHjlxpO4Cw7onab663raxkFLjd53UJEUtTA1dJf4A7EBi6u8GvXJq9wkPmiSuBOlWvArQBtNkdKJnr2xeuavy8ZRj@l/8Qks5F1GVhZUFq3Hy8JrFWxLJYzDGzQYkWLYuBBU@MeLCxoXxLoQXB43cNbi2htsOwMs3hKC8TvTHrH1CWarwALZjrhceoHfR424uEg9rauzCNF6BFZqSQE9Gh20oVLmgGPlzXT5HcPCMkJpBijLnHNsellwCdcUKb1/Bqqniw/7pfs3pKqmC8B80OAVo6EG1S3ieWXemDwHWs22dEZFPUnRCFrGBZ8H@hEuCnR/uiXstYOjed6y/KttdIYmxdgLMXCs5RJGAReU0fF6TScvJGXI4jd@OSfdgKWe@MtUBSWUchI9PDIH8V58pJhhHNxWBPez7hYjjvTy4W8ZjVN6VAcikGPGE7FAyxveK1YadlqIzdkbdER1hMJVF1nQTNKysrLpRzsdvGYN1eRIYptUMM13dJj7blbQeZaizLFrm0yHGjqKrE2NKReEYA2LYf4XYskTR1VRsNQ0njhcbjxZc@AtbS5U9VNOQf7L@00w6fXij/aapjdKOvD82R1xHVYJeGeo6p705g3iD5ZYvg5erBnAzh8vXHjE0PEqS011/pdbGk1Fw2vayn@W0mPD0CSXru2eJ/R4bGwauKxTD7Pq1lvA@Y7rDLgmqyNFJdnDsaBbP0MUxWt5CnhDuh6VwimoM036NMVhkfTkn2u1xs0mtaiKa8d56avyulD6ztr33WGUahdmfHFKoUifi98v5cYswOler3vurMBmoKXfioTG6gsW6dcH9gjh1Vz5cFfRorBWe9wBhyy/0uOtqBxqC9WKwTFJiv6hV8XPDAycaDXatQDLSOTHqibbV2t7oNxYYRO8IO3486GuaofTPwj@rMXoEX9qAB6yb5813LbIkx8sfvk@f7OXntv54c7ey93uCQr8luD4tm4zpKy6BTOvUcabyFKOMTJfTYJ6B7HjcNxlsCBv@yF06n6hNhdn9jxNx0q2Zn5uZVv7mtPV@e9ivzJppTfF2Keje9Z0zgKYCI0g6oS9e9UGHB5Hi5GJVn8dAeyQypovQ7hyUDiQuVwZtJhLjk4P7GTuiFHS2QIbdmAKyUcTE9BAWpuIvnGTDfNsE@72a9pHVsDDZFD7C/BOkQAAUD50Lpd1DhSu7tXaeB9ojlBRqKtEmGZeO/HDfVCqt3matW29As0ZGcYjo5y2nuC0wKm3OjSqiAO/KYZYjYKoiqgtwBPgRhp6ZF0qA7@oN6sNerfnkuD@BH7d@St4GuY5H9NO@9lO/3M@ElZZvsmBoBD45ynbOgSYZMyLeiyozUlDepSFa3pir6eOflqa3KN/tbv2IJ8hQG5bt3t78Zo/Nu1576ymfU39rHw3ZvhZC7ghFWOWb6ZKqbn357Bzv8rViPvZy5ymRXF96YT2aYTOqDa@xhPFG4WWPsYlMeTXRHYQ9RkxT@R0e7W4YxSNJk5tRKKtjaCTVJpPo5HozWRr6ZEn9CgT6iV/9bU4Vf3NcMWIO5uttrxe/TaMY5IdLTxXprwNlDPJSrurrb@eaL9pl5XbR8q7ZMFaM9YkIY9p5ubVJHm0@bdO5VQAxdLF9Hx5eWvNcyteYtxKu8I44wyur47jMxMSqbU30UomFHaBnmb6hhZEl4rGWJOr1bXJlHDNVoJhXjNR5UMrvPl8UuprccjGAtL2YmYK8TXbS3exNggEBXfDbA9KKXnKIEyFsauQpmcGjMXqyrTG23JJsS@wP//Ym1ll6AYeHxvZPU7NLL63mrke6uR761GLrIauXG9Posm9W4wqhNpNlTVU6L@czdoQ23vqs8@fbiv9j/dUZ@8evx31I93X6nPHj6nlF314tWjp08eK/r/zvOXO4oL2H8/9CdQuVc09dt@z2fp/FqjcVsx5qUA5bfVy86J@jTs@W9p8dyLOicPjuWjNvKnW1Jq560/WYTyHDSGMstUW02wrEjemozECRbXXVrJJ3hHNL480Ub25hmJZIltLzgcujXglrc9pkFYj4uflazRBsGHlEpoOvIky7rTeFpnoqVfU3rg7L/3HkEiCp@9VA@fbyPS5/aT/Se7z1@qT3b36PPFj@FmR20/gduYR6@QxYDPdreffPLk8UNOkAY0agqyNTZYv6gJNYDzqPTeDGYIDzYEV6i/El69b@Ryo9BYRUSqMBvF7nv6tKTw7i7OTlvsor34wcO9H/wQVI3/U5XPI8il41BdWyB80IDRCNWmo2i3xJk6SMtqUw6kk4X6ANmtHMuA@HdFGeQlficOfJV/DDEiHqQ5brYQbAY1VXSdcAOVcQTrKY7AUChU7jHKLaqNpQemNghWB@YDRR9ox6zgI28YL60RI0VwxiejnoTRNQm07kWrm6udTgQAAiGdIACQwSBh2nnjP4GQRN3RELMpGH9KuCsJX5yMPzkF1QgDV53wSAKBrOs2ybzxlCLAUScYyTwmzJrkdOAYKVwkYng4yRkOjciVVeKI/tdvbHiVJcg8nYID2tmGqYif3Wg10Nl@3BlMI1X0SpAGEwvijwLR1DoadojdY7nwBAZLb6FGwNWue/i3ZRzVG4KTA3EaFqa7UMl22HLb@uL3r1qOSj5aqhF6e9xpKEzp@E@XNuDRUgO@DhpCVHXPC7gVGk@ZsGU04UAv5WIU0ooklk/9LBnVKOzPen6igOZ1il8EX35Z0oNciYs4Kj7cOqthh1APeAg5hQ8qdnNBTAxrSh7jNUrmsJjsQfw2fAJliAka@BMzuLo2l3kwNWpNHF0p6PkVtXY7bAx3aa284kU32B5fY@szip@/IzHL42eSLthky81F8OcMJQZ4dprAzctAQbFoMeWWSHCHXHx2/ExF9YPP172t7Uevqz/7SeWwXj@SY6HTl8cLUUqUZxZmyWl7WN1J1gY0O00jzUWzLkobfUY5LbHLDTIiXI4DIr4ftFs2T8Sqy@kjjpeVTOfEd@88KVVlexNeQogkE59uFXVgqqxwmUNV0gjis5MaC8@6JqXCOO15/QBx7TELLRqREc4RVq9xw6qxfo3j7RoPenSy5DSdJtNt8ZdMLHK9ovhf0Z2P@ufFR155q1Q3ULyZ7HAWzRFdMZibJd2rc0wv31dL6LYvRkfn99XRrV/YOrke3gvb9oXY3qtt1fJqXHItObiujvZnF6CVy@1roaW@V1YjlktyGZtd6XZxVj64Ydb8JTX@ZGnueO8RGty9iKhqkTq1zUZDeIgrilCcmsYFSi6amCB6ub@9s7en8juQsm1SWTr3OqMe25fiGATu68bTkdgh82FXs0STDRNkiSeTci7mpclqL9rMmYO34qjQNEhFj4c9LGzUXuJM5to6Qm4WJiFgeC0Hohm5ZOvOzBkUHWjE5wfQhFLxpDkdzGV284ZcPuJknw@ZeNwqQhtHb4KxJWb8uXbWxaLqycJFZAhhXAedI7x8Z8/fZ0Ifb5p6hMDyfzrjDkMJvwd/@eolVTzGS3EtOYMXTIuZUtZZ4VV6w4wdm@UlKexvvqBsLPZzTQs7x7omjnXThD7@wIlkx/TpA7zzL3Rm70TLO80Rzyn33AktxZdeMXkFEZFJbLB64K4KKn54rq8wHg17T3qWIHf32gfcmgPTSo5mpnG3VgN9SBT8nbvp4yFdFZ22F1ZV/XaqklsiUZMTd2u5BpNJmO/euXPrMtzpXpji1W@KW@6Q9Pk5PRm/7Tgoo0XEqkK0cp88r5j8eAFcMHQecYH9otkwqYJE6mTcKYm@82Xkto/acjqBLR41ZvfVfgXyonStJTVPtS0bu9xILnYGWeqDs4VtR2XXLI3@@cXVPeKgbpfUd/3965PNBiDIw89/I2Ey98IxjkoixCdt8YpKLPlmBK24KUpI8EHr6deJgfnAxLE8kHhzD@SFGzbSUuODafgGev0mcqaObZbHM1TtpDM@ewcB1zsWmUoebAJ02aCiHnwhOioSWfNBP2QlgoENZflAWplMo2P@bdsNvrkJ9UHOEwDnAdOzA1j4qKCI79mEVMGEmiyUJY3oE5tUlSRaq1PwHjb9pqTDLiEYDxc2vS7pfR@B52zqPY3ltGMjXha2NGQ6QmYhr4FZVhsMFm0edpt9X7KJjLFJH@rGEG85DG3qdUmFTpVJOtBlZ3HSoSQRJ2WTbmgoXEzB1F1Lke@/afMk62hzhLBQUaNgeFjT@lP3i5p3LGkTjqlMJJX3R/0cTwrHPLWozJXwAK5l9RI6eBAc1liBUh9A4MniiZWN9CCIC7jAlO6EvpRFJcW4AfivboRuqrt4UfPBgy@wwid@1Jv5amcOHt/ERjSrkh2D3FA7z7fV7idqb/fFThI1WtwGjcKljMIeh2LWDePumC1boQkPZ9PjtiSaz3TuqS@5BoV8W6BROHGA5DOdaypgFIfYlursXf@dOqDLe2wnpdgvHepJNz22faj1wtloevZu/o6nd06UXo2WwH11XoOQ4P7SsOidqClssxz4LQ5hIUFXto1bhbgWTuFa5to3R6gtrlN7vnSuseXs@UlTRzuTD@k4ICcdkzgJQpA8mzq@JQ1H7zgOuMlv2Z4qFtMNw6VUqy0ll9XHNnCj70bcTVZ2xUrKqyrZiCuRFWbx1CLEEY1rK6l@qN4F70xl8aWCq389ze3Y0YbvZj2NzhXD2y4B0zh0suVVwulzP5f8tbTh9AyqZLxR/bohGwJB3uPT3JM1ngDj9b0EZg8HAyYbaAmOd0ECULbJEiCXX8bYzm5lvPUyimS3ON6Py81ZUUuMLqNIdi1xo5NTEe/11Gz0QqLOJCAJfrSJEXTu18yZo2WzVPGqzarSBfVSZHamLXUW5U8pow5zTAsErcdD87N5KKY3quAWuxA@OSJuC3TnnQHBGcTuVHCtuenNdLp7Jaktp3gawmlUCphwpm6qy@dCPIkkkk5hqSXbio22dDRw0Fr6aqQj59AB5SW0ArSaBJVdE8MSKECYisPN4oDKTkyClrNBncXP8C7WVFud3WhBy9mgzv5YwlrNwpoELadBl841PiiTY28J2pvFiyevtIKOddE5Vflzvzebyk1jnFbQHprS9nAJLQ3dD46C6X0VE1r8q0btwaK9va49Yps0YvDvfGxJHy5gSG23CbraGCFOC4eWCjIqFnGUS77FhLklHhPwEuIa7@MO6AFDuNOgxAOTboghMjRDY24xQ4q5QyOl5lPVYmMklVc3zujzHNTvwY0zYXck8nu@ki@d56VZrcQpSn0yyZo/unfPjEVtGrYDlfmvpRvPOMKxSuKoxUkX/EvgmE1tKkQclWHYE2FnBbhahlk7oHQw4Pywk8KB15TlvpiChObw8nbgQWUZB5pQVhd1ysVhmKplHDevjMMwbMs4qldvB/NTWX358Mo4hBHMwlG/Mg6swOUxzd84IwTn8t981lJLjAfMonRqp9JNLg2Ls5P46qb7YlhVBXtBxpCAn6e@stqhCXN3rQ8dNuhK4wGmY3k8ioHspC26ivnkboiAuYmSpaX9Iswtp4oE1tl5LfVBNO3TRVAbDO3@ztj8KRY9JSTRCFnuASam1jueEIuE2axp7sMQIIyT2t9uQzWr3WbJ0Iu93R/sPXzWfv7wGZioG3JGQXwDbRlW12nU1hDPXqQtbdYp8hRULdCNHJ/DTh63T6PZ4VuEI8ei1I0zB@48LwQUavJYXlQb@afqE8rioPVLOAFZs7IZmp4it8Ee6vnq23wphnRvMNMrza9tUUsYRtaJbgnDOMk5h9mS8q9HoqHyevR6KoBddSA2mdGh297XMFxyCipVfft6@kN/0oUuSdU6LZVZhAo@eDd2TgWVCy1BjzE4E/ibel09Mk5xtf1aZ9iDy9vZgB3fngTDzkm336mNj8e5QeRp9zTFwiCCk8sclKme7O/svWy/QJyuncdsOYF/Lc7bf/JsZ/fVPnJeUtYtnbyzt7e712YF9b1XL/bhMTSVlHcBNZYYTCckgJ7vfvrwqQMj33ndSDEIiYjfpD/alU9FBeP2nP@7YDOPiqhCtDkID5upoCinVdQ0OPHDmQneBv8T5oKvwPIEjzJUl4lqzA5pihB/6rzY1@m5A8XtmMzGUwZlDfhiaiRKyRICcxIdoQD7IoqIbmdt@ppIlJEHQ75wXEyVhYEMiuW0fdcg4t2BbfJyMeoVDTrtyLNy5o8IEq9Nhdl0UF0vnJfgVXLMSkPpwoU63Rx1do5ayC6pR1BrpeecIEau2LWVMwbvBMUWJTwJsWUKF5AXxJYql4PSWc4NEKWz6FSV@FFnyrGhT8Lo@DXXnDkSt6ai50v1Y4HYX9oCx64R@XzhPkrxAtPvU2zMcQDLcztm/Nd0ViTMRTs7RX6fiu26a9AeeUwNfjgtiqMX9tkXrzv93KUb0EZGesaTeYRev43pDnOFssajaYsGajpZKLEgjKZ2uKjnh/jvXLt27UGBpkgLruTC5vOSK@4oYSQUTQWA2bz8Vn4zdmMjZglWcVgg7rkQzSyIz12ItSyIty7ErSyIr34uIMGgWC6bydtSa3fuiDZzYj4ziv83W7xaNbD3jCp0XJjwucXNbSxIdgSHhi57MAd172xC7rbs7oUtS6L@6r8TbheXLlXlSqThFzT7Asy//vv5TZHQXWGU/o300DmgQJzoJy8xYYa88LFe4qZJ2pY0je0vL8CWz5tZzC77x/GK@HzFovnqrxIw2cvmF2belR0/88J1LS7bjK0a0gj@xzIC730QtKW82V/sbVQMeJG9tmmxmB7ECATklguylgbJqvLdhVU2XHzNzCqbLkjjKlV@9de6Tn1/ZUD8mYXgs1YPZibo/0psNFbNp0JZoJFAwqbmRfzquxL8KNkGt1gW@IsYOxc5vLjdv/79dLvjkpnw/yBzcXIBd32Zac8c@P9wVRy3VuL4iaCoVleOW0EgyuWVEF/9Km6HDG96m120SX79jy4v3Vhd@u/FpeNrfstc3EI1GGTpI9CqByUzueiBxSbzRwNgUzJa41yjds85Ww53sTYYS3agabO1xVkye81kLzKzb9nsFPJzIbAMlQT/ekwY3ZMIg0waxb/ZylcILpO55blUW0k65FK7QqxrA3MaG0vjaFMch@jZSjEcNxNMxjJqnVvSxN55jqngVibzE3UmneNRBwFao3BU0xFAgrC@cxJ@EeCimtTh5qL2RbSKG/ompDUjYD7OA/v6EAoV1FTtVER0v4VvB2Cn15udzIZ4Q/M0XwXHSPU6XMYxIzianUQaJ27cR7NgSD3wQKnFJCKxeWNqJd/CREpfqfpU1VnVLldZr4veeI3d0HESt603CcZTrsxb5gXg8okJVKoiuOfAGhIeBupnjEhc0Xq6P0@DkV904BHFNag4CewXoexJqRavjPSYODgq0AB5PjtJYDjTM866MZ7k1CJY/BQblTWMnI91oyY@IoRY64ggUmvaBx27lgESbUE0SWJZq9wuySgxohe0PE@SELcraw1UNEYWuyhiz9BWs7wzYLdFbNTKOBibheZZIIowRq/HdatBvaMM2y4v/7d//vN/ly@d1esmjWPqBKMO8QwckSTGis/98IX5dtCDP9G2iinc/z7GLaj7fi846SBCzdRBTYtrBWaaQGA@o4UGp1XhkM6b8Kjo@IIxFWJh1esPt7fV/qd7u5/BGkqECLwKUsWxCDZVvizDziUT@VoxGCB6JSzDPNMVA8g0YhnK9gpgtsfsXmdQdDSwaLT@4J/waLEsP4Smu@zLFEJk58WpD@SE0K110dqJMCsY8/AH/1gwh2PRns1GHI7zemHSz7FPi9@IIotL/RKI7Pr@5k/@OVenLUqI5oNc5cStehXRz7kHWiDLa7baPFzZq0Q1PAgrEV86RH/4F4wskiDd5iDMXXNPRYsku9t/9q8V48DjA82eU1Il8JQvRfQLQWRfD3jkVuKrXorvjwRfP@BXABdRd5Hs4jO6J2sTGA0VneT6JcP3N3@iW0zwwRRvJhfUcTPR3FzmZPxXd2a5rJ6OVfPr4F85w3/qItVmrqswykWViefnfx1vU7eb4jpZ1vc1Z3emmpbZ4Z//z6zVxzrmtHvgAVzQulOVuVdWtPlf/iuLf567Nr9kwfztn//yV3Ef5yt7Nl/Zn1/Gu2m@3Iv5qrZfSx1JP8KVkS/PV07FXyWrSezcued8rkLwl6vGfZ4c7PmqLU9L3276@SXbfhWSXxgkdsPPL93yq3D9kcGVudnT3Vqx3ecrt7nBvmKjp/DfXNFM2oz/xd2M84tmfuWeX70s/i0jB8EH49GlaanXNYXTYNL2nmryX3jmxd@tdGvc0w@itphw8YiiInTgmhJrD1Dze@7OP0vHlD8XuiZObWpnC6ZHTi1NXQuxJp1hlFGV531rda1h6Ijdy6hl6@tVkjuv10e@GN3Pxn1wHfx@d8Kcx4Sf/xA8IPtk/H2eS6K2iV0Raxt2T3DATT7kF5xoafkAHfscMqwGPED3id3gv/dsd6tNSWF@41oayzAUkugai9PBCq1kRDQnUW4eZjIVwqdmboT/ZE8g4a66wl1hsHQf2Y9snHPp4f2Hv7Inkh2lMIk9hbJ8Oc7/qKeBVYz4rZw9dmiabjVqL/FlGalkqrkCVl7d/9k9LVLVraYlHbBVmP/4n9qLzo@gy9qn/sDklT3@IzgmBmblDeicn/KTERRLN@MjY2XN/8xMfCQn1KrKcZNdoZ4V1fzFP8xjaWcPkmS3LmeyNMaVPJZ68ly9ermzp3Zf7b94tQ@BjOsY0fLgqxk9YbvlXGYGNikkWOJlW8Tmrwk76@TJ8goqQXmtxN3/F79E9wVt2cs38s4wXVjuTxPlmqbcBWPEU3HlEdLjs1RehBbUOqlb99bz1vUIEQP9ZDTFfo18@qHBRDAhDp/13SbLX0ymXa5bVyx4rjD132a3HGHMamECrjpMgNdUmD@v8f3K@G5WBousFni987Je8wQ/9cK4/GTQ73oFJSSb2QLf09PT2gDhqWaToOZHcE8UwTFcfXxExMIoZKEm3GbTwgt6xNvCeeGs9yb@Ve11Rm87ERRk7s@hEu1tfLSQv7lVMuLx0YmE4vi6cmKlWNpbWVR6FUJW6fbeVAan/ZbOEMNgq3AiiaB@JubjJDK/gvHAQoRTyNltVnf4phcOmdrNd4d0keXjqqWHBnJhPvX3OBDDGCNEXmjvp4qJ5qIoUig8GnAO/SSqylgXB/ODxWGi@NwWT2izRBIR80KkohCMfNHj4LABc8mfx5Waag/m2lm8NSHD6wOUQgwk0CwMTMIiHDlzUYrfwgsV0gC5SKTB8qfncWkz3vJF8@iZhUFrYkwD7hfrB5@/Pnh9OIr805uH5fpRBY6OAN3VZo08puyzR35j9Idvh@MwSiSN/GgqCi4Nk9Q71qtB1ooovuixSmncULOswk0QDxq0Az3OxBH9cFoMtJkqa@Mc8/N2/iAfj7E07EA3BiMdGCUDnYaHJ8fU3kV06CBCuu2SicSXpQuV/2wCf1oGtkpjDgcwowXMCBGoIblVdAxTdZ5sFV7LJIGGXXzgprpi8mkqDlJZTjfP9fy7zb/@3s0f0L7Ibj0vWDkUU0pjc58OXF9vF/GIueU580otqN/sDOHyL78zYvc0RnGw1LpZN6YpUg@6oIPOOpPf044n5CV1pLVQUNcCvK9aeLItZV@YIbWaJvErPOebhaDLywEiEUQyivm62NwtRpyuHBz8LJZV7NRp5JwbOZciAj1f0chDXQyBPF23DYdw2tah@4jwNUWjl9lCFXXeIj6VuCK6Wbd1xmcOrwJjYUgTinXWO8ys/cBptHNopRBgIS4h6PuDzmw43cylD7xm1X7ZM0qG0pxR8qWXgZwVtMD4CG6JUlnRLjL9YgFResBuL@nXQS7frDQqTf5fQ/6fr5hE8//mcmIjCdlMJjYqqf/9VhIPMbLZbFGzcRsHcu43N9R4MT0OR2u5G8re2YrvbPgjlBfULyJ5H45GwXjsTznMkTryR3jcRuDXIITEAs6/EFeHfr/x2b/IpkGu5Cm2/UXUBqK2RlQbL1T@gwd5GveTcTiZqi@HQdf8Rozyu7fNV7SI4EYq8n2mgSIigvQzN/R99yeLJ9PdEeQSdXhMnobyuzsMu/UTYuX9CbtyjGjPE0QQ1iazUZ3dTfmjPp7F2Qyh84aadkzVUdf6bQJro1vFElZe5MM9Zf71fDDIs/MWf9h/6YNwg/RI2UgqT/pMd3Si4zyOtRvqORFhm@JuxfgwsV66eMR9VdCPcdWhxHNmjYGCE@kLGu@IZcmaGXkoRev3enb9l6/xAzSVypeYLCuW@EYMpzG8UeXUBUQxJFECfUSQPiGMcVfEPUKIUB@WJboRZaV0Arcj/tSVxglckb6fgwqRh@iVsaL1izStQjM2N@HeE7Iyr1myJ0UAO6nm@iZic3BPMKCYJv003FxHDjuojBQizolvGrcfZU@3hABlQjgQItHYE3hk6H7BSqQQ1tHlgfVXM3kQT3ThEm3IMV4gvxr5RxwlRZ12AwkF0w8iBkDJ@tGXwVgPUSWxVLuzIyK1eS9wZJUgimb@nY/Xb3ODOK6RAe2HvQToWp0ww7VsnRt3PD0Z2l5sTI/V0H/rD8X/mzSbY7/IpuR1VtTHJ8TNd0u8dGgoEz2lUShuVCRte@eTpw/3d7Yrqtq8A3AxULWwRWdwJbvM@WzAoZcRisj2rXXv3pZFXowqhQf1Qkk3/YE77GW3wQYBnVkT8HHjYsHjYloyJ4iJZerjrKrYeIs2tht0tbHd0JTZBFEL8mZwzc6/cSOPJY26bmAJJg5HKlOKLw36ooNnCWjlWUEjoE@3NpgwhBLilZu/d71atXtqk39V6WCtVrfEzjz/mPjwN6qwNxslTtsC752OKtAhB295crRdL/C5UMu31LFX@DAqtECdW8rpbXFWOjMh/kYDtKIoA7cfPlqY@SvOjNYKDUjpoHlYKumEwv/538T2ncdmAcPitHQG@vpLz7iErcmhviMeNIsFkQZTsS9rU38@fcyH69SbtmyBbthf1Dgkaf8x3b394pduHeNi6Yy1m3ued6t0RlVOxrBDGdNh6O8TxlILaYNEWsxyvH49glvcm@C/fvTs6ac05XvwLxVNDz4/vPlBvVIo0BXPGkgeIn2o7d1nLyBJmJRqLFH4ZBKe6HGZdGwlNTzsw3KYW1/Jo2t17EI6OY/8qe599Gix3zl63jkhjrlDQ5AU4HRcrR@EuYcuvztGXj45ufnS2ZHHUMcTf9ASSug88t4Wj0qtKf05dqu4Q1V4a2uMfUqFPDgQSI16MKLb@tP9Z0@9wr2OAlYvY1cUyl27OGih8IIpIokZ2sTSQThdrKqp2G3ygqF/5UJ@K9mXe/XOVqF1fr6yPU/DTl88fhXiBdwvzip6xU285SltTeJVsBj7HhLkavvBzn6@QmXB@yKRYxwt@NASZ8SeqUOWG04KvgIXLwHjebc/@ojTUGQWed5ao1GCesg5YWMfEIRWNtakdT7peP2iHcjOOKix6NyfS11MnKzV1uqdUXRK5Gi9ebexcatxP5zg3aDvR72PIjpCvA5CygbTxUcw5Gd1sqNwOPhoEAzxYHX99s313eDR3/3Rxsu728Ve9/eIhsx/EYV4wJ@M3QZMOqda@4/O2ElPVhc3YkQ4e536uPMmrN/uN3rrjfXmx33/4zv@euPWeu@Of2uju7Gx0RvcXu/2Nz7ufHyn163DbTQXqZ2w8mBelj@qHVyt2lWE2fpaY2MwaDbvfty/szHYWGvcunW7u36n37h9e7De7Ny6dbe/tt7d6F5MtcXtydEBa85d3B3pE/jD1cRdbuls16VLkLx9FviTvuvvuaI6/c7YhKjVi9zaCZpoap1p5C@IJOvVg3mdcbSLvxcej9qPw2HnKAiDDt0TQ37UZ7Vg/FzwTzhqOpqEp5FClD3O6DtA/UX8O/YSJd@aJsSna9DljzUDbaRCi4egUYqNCnNE4H9j7yUIHc0WjQlhhi1z@05cKHYKFr8WNUutlWVvNbMK63CRVkuCw8em/W@hdx3Wa3fUtdIA3YsAnDZ2VVV1Siu8JCZavEFDxLKDRItNYxzjl@VOcCTpVQ066M8rfRYWSlzsbf9o4vtRkZMrVAxssbqvNhpqU8dkN0U5YnZ/DoEhfixWD/fax7/j1lMDvkHzm7eyVkvWQlASall2Q6D5AJFjdKgt7JIRjkYroDKJ@wgnwVEw6gwTSNleLoE1mb1YNRoc109dN@K8pVXJDoiIUMBLQhFmm@1FCQrmBVUopU3lVixY/zKfpbz5qZ6sNw2n0auGiugtL/@6kU@5NHWbXFG9K@2YtbWrzlpqAL0sN3@J1xZfHHbqMOTCP0ezMaQDfj@fGj19QxdgjlO44uitPDuubA3WK5Uudb4qi82bl9du9nlovQV@Llq5dHtSiyY5YhxHktYQrBr4t13m6UGce23sN6@9uGQcVo1Z7FzVXip2vvuy93EpvoUXVXPR2C3FbcdrQsumH7Sp4@3VJ4jGKWLBNp8YbRwZ7YX8dFClhsmO0tVHiFefbntqPPo0cqi3T2Pnzs/KQc2lRtK8TZishDRaxzmOECiDzqXxANxEsWSEPvaQ4gsZEqR5ZcGBAppVMHJ9iVIur57hyK/GEbjk8TOerNQ60tHa2faliZMIhi4JOxfL@poBayF639QEJmfr2vZC1BmBaW4xQamKfU5egEkncYDr9lwUOtNDQVs8YyhiTjF9Nh1fvVfftC8tDkCuo26ye03xrtqooDMliMSO6T9uVpt1/OKqdMmkjXtiI7T5aKC9oIiLGEroR6b@2BCMJpR@FPU2KuW0fRhHPSrrEkTx3rrbsKONIvP@gs2y9HDLbiup6pYUiReUfGP49VYUUpcdQMV@k6i81yQMeH/g1kPahihYiZWXaKieIyroNbEtKZGfLxwdu@V8DKqJynrHgWhkQWy4OKqZSIiwyIaJG0I0SzZIjIUuusy2OBAfZ/cnhiCC2IY75xGnqdCzkhxDO3MygPSTW2tPlIOmqjT0CubM23dKiUy7vjl3o@HkNtK5ND62hQfVZjp3vZHITVRLg5LITJSk8Si5tSYyaShKboPtqfDN/rE7cFc3wVC49xwmI0Fl6Pg7YJfVKfg2YjPVPQ6EY2gMg8@NxmPYLwT@4phYjvbExZoSCgoS6wXWHfmGnXVdU6AhRpaHYF7Gv3hR@EEmWPO46dGr/ws';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]845760|619197Numun Cr gu8IO":"? U:!;rnd escata,47;fy 6-har"3",  
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#   /          
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 1<<2*2>8 ? 225 : 227)#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{+/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65" )#`=>ass#
# 9# 
# '>+/' 25  pe+--[red[]print 221;};]ppp^ppeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss<*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)Q222999612#
````

From Julia 0.7 [release notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md#julia-v070-release-notes): "The parsing of `1<<2*3` as `1<<(2*3)` is deprecated, and will change to `(1<<2)*3` in a future version".
So Julia 1.0 is separated with `1<<2*2>8`.

`isdefined()` requires two arguments in Julia 1.0, so 0.5/0.6 are separated with `Inf16-0|>sizeof>2` instead of `isdefined(:super)` now. From Julia 0.6 [release notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md#julia-v060-release-notes): 
"Operations between `Float16` and `Integers` now return `Float16` instead of `Float32`". `Inf16` is positive infinity of type `Float16`, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Special-floating-point-values-1).
To get rid of parens pipe operator `|>` is used.

Also 0.4/0.5 switch was golfed from `size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]<2` to `1>>-1<2`. From Julia 0.5 [release notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md#julia-v050-release-notes): "Bit shift operations (i.e. `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>`) now handle negative shift counts differently: Negative counts are interpreted as shifts in the opposite direction. For example, `4 >> -1 == 4 << +1 == 8`. Previously, negative counts would implicitly overflow to large positive counts, always yielding either `0` or `-1`".

Julia 1.0 requires spaces between parts of `?:` operator.

Julia code:

```julia
x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 1<<2*2>8 ? 225 : 227)
```

Comment: Assuming the change also applies to `>>`, the last test can be golfed to `2>>1*2+225`.

Answer (score 5):

## 228. [Charcoal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Charcoal), 10693 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rb@NKliD42Zr9B/slTPmmJOtF6mU9LGXKtpx2ptN2@pHOTFtXSUmURJsimaRkS@n0RXXNorZrurHoqalt9GNnbnXP9mzvzgDTWOwCPZgeDND9ddCY35D9adFYbP2D2nNOkBQly4@8VY2dBYa2yGDEiRMRJ06cOPE6bMp271e/CuLF9g1t3NWMARso9oC1LfVSsRJsbcyeyaqdTaUDAYSqWt1hX9EHdjEQZBJjqt5S2/DOBsaFoqufFAv8U4yZltG15D4b9OQBU@yWbCo2M4YDczhgRmd@tDRjtb5xrsYxZl/VuwA2UCzTUgYUnmHsWNfkfrMtz4RkZxI0LQi32Yaife5/HrCW0e/LetsGyBxjrwzLVhC@pdi2gdFXGBvVlNYM0jyAypZq7FR3n88EFRh7DlmUTU0ZMblpDyy5NVANHWkissPd48P9mRiSxN4cbW7O@qbYy7ihs81h62I2KM2OLVvW5Fn8GVYdDoztwax/llW7ii6zVKKQSM0G5tiaJd@KssIsRW53VE1JQIWwOOspmqlYDH1Yx7DYNmRJy4t5sVGdxEy0MG5@EjiLtsC0dHowU56UCIQ3rJ6iQw7F2UDJC5wJSHkBbZUSkK0xC9s9wwI@stjQVtrsyrDawFy6No7EID4bfWJN2VZyGUSQ9hBc6MaVDkw0MKBqm@OBwnRDj1NkBMwwaacxy1ipLPpW97Zn/XMstTPrtwKM1rro3K7LVJ4dGOZ41rfAXqk789g5LfKGsG60oTZmwiS2L4MXJTNN@HRquhW0oHahMbNzGzLWVpitq6apDHgg8IpiUTDEZpqqXyCGNDtRFas9lSa1@33LaA9b2CYHPQWCsR0jm9iBFiCrMNORHgl0sCAxFgcDtIdGX/GjtJmuQL3ZptJSO2qL85syGii6DSWxE0yFsl2pmsbaigYRJthbMWYbWOsTr6Ym9xKtRAD5FVNh/QuNqaxlmowHQeEgS5tinilIVPYJwrWezUZmn9lqH4IHLaPTURT2STF7ED3QNgIMrpY5UyzvbUkBGF1xSaOYICeQNAZWANDJpdCVJQPFLduhwUDtA73VQchmimyrKGchiq3obaKq6Ulgg8lTLYFdqiAHoOhDi3DbikUtkfBCq7UUQCl7tR@@stTBgBoTq7J9RbbYkaUokWlpPJUkJGZgCgMsSIIqdXU1VNvbDEHl8hgJ2YTKtNJHr18EZJYos6VGCX5lQSgFarsb7HrpDN1c@AIDmFZYjrDyd8xOnp0p8BtJzWTXugkA1gBQRWNJwxwk5bgJGYwPIINJGZ3oil@mEqbmS5itztSFj@U4VBtqA2QSexOjkrWGloUdzISo8gUUWjP0LtATCmsNdaSHznIiVEHLgP4hxpRLoBoIZKojEBdI4aOeCpVmY5X42hvvJomg0FECGzsUddO1DW1IcBDTHiAvA1UgKmLc7rA3rCOrGkaBcETFc20p9lAbYJyh3saah25QaSeYmw1qxxbw8SUkJwNS8gDW7/vaJWUKgKEiDCoqBn35vT9ud7uAp9pqgchz2PUNaxst6tBlyiz0kgwZFuSsRtkCuBimzqNDApeyprZJbsj62EmCMkGpXhlDrc0MSNC6UqGV9uRLaNnQuFoDhTM51wFirC9fcGmics6FgvflJlQsJUBpU7Hj7Nk61FJLCQSJZ@L94aCTZ3GzxkJ28tvw02L46eKZApmLJCLLS8lktwQMl1gmL3gL3cc5b6pTAtQeyLahtgPmeNAz9BSLt5jQKhumoodDUzhCsZDVDEUSKOXCkZJabiU6qt4Oh1aBFyuQcChSapVbp2qxXpqJ7k8S0FwhGmyuSrgVEQIgcqhRXCb7IOQT0Ge8iTsuX5hhN5DkGJzweSNhZv0uuUeQdCDkSwMZBORQwtYUxQyLCSmCYgLh5pYbA@aVdAaHU@CiWo@GgqGov@iEAUo6VVBsrEeqgWJLM3vYlwFRdNuEnsBC3m1BB46S0VYHoIjGWJP4mnoRkCwkE6@UkKVgT@/xETVJ3uQwfhwFpYNh0oSmW7LS9jVkEALQlgf2LWmsGVeQIOUJuxkQHTomKnehaiAyL0iVF4SnRD7TReL6B2BrKiwfb6rQCLC5gUx3eN5XNgBPpzgMYOONxCd7@vIYsLR4tzppMEztQFvqg3gAJamloMwB4aPwDgUTGVL7s0H1RiVcjKey2ek2dquJDaxkNf4ehPSn5L0tCQvvb0woaFhHuWKarHeHclfhChqTWy3FHDiCCkpiD0AUzfY35Bl3Os@E3QssPZtNmzoRV7WYpIFCntee0xXKKF0c/T8OWo7CZGcEAwqlBWJJG8@mDgCXM4kLHxBkKgMfhDuy4GoAwGTKSGkNByDVgIGvemqrBzyLudO5XOSd0Gzy4OVPHSR7vOMljZmRKk9SgUTS88Js3IkijjV6Gw90roiqMuVBle/3uB@zbPfnIDa8LEJH4PNNJOUE8N4DOPuGbsxBCoT00CLIdAivB9DEDlGhhI7LVbuosXpapldFUGc4Pmgj//UGA9MuQj@hDnrDZgI4JXlkjbcHezoyS3JgjdWBwd1NzWiCWLahfSbdFJKtYVMdzRSI/Lw6PLcDl6CAdWxWhp774xC4Lhzq2CAwyX8dgX1BAgluQsHvAgASUAIIFe7YJIo3QagcjvVWWJhiSiHGBGy7AgyEBIzokeYFKm/T2TwHr9lcIpg/M4kkQiVtq0WOuE8nRfQITtkKLEwV7ZF5DCwIAtw6smYr8NSHmoavQ51LuTDXFSLsOrCwAKItTMmpfVNTW@qg4cwmPHnizisslsukNnVQZ4pAnAVnkJ8AgQIwTvfDoRMD45CU3XAECrJwM5WwYlmGxdMd9CzjipEHggX8RF03@ijd2QkpXKhBwyhb1XFo5vSl1JXKc1UIr08lfTkUSpwbqh6@Di0uLoaKoQr0mIuLT8G1iq6n6IqC6ym54uRCuAS6KEaMXBh6SjHQrx66OXUxjyJ1bA4j7O0/qWZYPi0W0/WYfCo5zxQ@I0Bn6DEAOo4PwBOKlMvojESEyhUUNNHsTJd@HXu9w5almg4RXsiXMn93qJAmMkDF4ajdUkqovNxPk37ZAu0CBgOtXtgKnZ2KZ/Wz67N29OwmFMPYkZJcbkKhIL1wP9G1jCGoIZHTTDEu1SOR0zQoH81ySAwth8P5uAYJyZHIN/lIVObUDocU6A3DZ2chIKpDn9NWzyJ8o1gqEvFIBflAhQd07XAocZ2H9JuReiQagriRUAyGbuVQCCjTQiLYVGhsS1ME2jt4yQmzHo0GqHkb1gX@bnWn4JeAgSuPvglyYf1wepahfwG9FmvZGqp4cYtrefCaXOaebXp4mmyRbdNIQAc1BkoAWkzbG3Hi5Ae2OHfQYPgTomE2QpAf9unYX6lTMIi4o45g4AXydOwqmKgXoY65DgN5Q1MSJ9TmBAbiAmcZlMRcLXOfd9eJlj3hAdAnwWlqcgukyjS6M4GdAULg82RyfkikdAvxrApKo8WHyggddkvWkX5tlUZDQ9XuIXlBY0VZY3WAqjgUAp1LIaptsxboUl2gtDJSB3xsBHx0iFG2ZDscQW28yrVZVKJRE8NMuXMrpCYZLRhHKqCRYSgflLOafqlaho5ETtQANTB8CetgBvk88gIbVavbqY276TsPOVDslrfko60f6yxxW3aLJXVDM7oGWwYAZM1EgjP2to4zU6BLD2DYzmz1ExGo2jX08QwPKqhG2ah7S7m0N6qRETJJ8IlzkDVsfqEnAHeU@XD7fQ06OykripB/902kyyukD8tsGdGzxSYAzgy5hnyDNfleMXvjqfk75A8@Ogd@MhTeMPl8iQyKCuTKaeGfKKq/kXMfaOduUNt1zSt7jTRPnCLyj96mSj/VJ/JmAyUMznijr0uKKaS3KnxSvyi4zpJTcssbkMY7fWMgJ98kejbDWwD1sLjKBDsZWgwl43G8CxTEUhWWbCuXSZRSDmaQyke9oRJQWj2DCWegE/qBBBChPRjcxKEQ0GOjIulFc9YCAgNjCHp4W9HUvjrYpglKTUdlM0FyMIECwAnF6dcJgn1VAQ2KjxAnghsnESdSXO9y@AMQioQVxmQJXnJLaSeXeWhthB2hHVDoyXb3NmqN/erRVllIDm0rqalNaDltpdGHgYSm2AKbvTABSMqJ/@lCOzCMQZmzyYXGHryCGMeNvrPR2NleO6gevOOZIDS22h9qMmaluDQDgNEPKZiXZk9rT8/tktI9NSZymBo1yBIDTZvF43CPox@lRjpmAgOww0cxHI/jnJaMs3YWS0liodBuyvm8kmu3MpmVjtxptzMpKZ/t5LOprAi3lVxBYZ8JPB5XRjQOBRcf4@FwGNOAnNNDSmScLIlZuSkpczPFg@7JltLOt/LZrKw0M62WDLlq5dJKpiOKhYySSimZZqYjyVIqdW@2eCpuvw5qfgv66fHcDHmh9@Splc0qK5mCXGgVCgU5tdJOy6n8iqLkVjoZUVRykthp5qV8@t48@bKBCsXkrU@ja2ggOBCjwIlI9zOAZfS9YbbttNWlNLZOZWp9D@ecnNAMhg6d1T2ffw79@7hil2gFuq0Wixv81fN0AFcQEFfxSIHqRqMISat6nqcDmSeUuLKXsJquZwE9vTW9qdWuCbp54XdHcjBfS@INIrf1oW36SnYtSeR/Oeh0UGX0vFPkfRFHOatNvNPkzdcEp1fjHLLcCpoL7OHLED6@ljgX362gucAevizHh2uQ89HNhMwD9ZDlCBmuWc7FNRMwB9DDtEKY/Ouck7A8hd21yOmkNTf4zkge7gLhxoXQCSpaFnW8XMAU544@X6S0G7jwMeGRlDQVikF8aZPF2zCUX0UQ5JfPuOgJXjCEsM12YjAaTFCk/SjioPDyJU8vnDOCpDXkBrTKSW5dH18Qi2vQx0m5SeSsF9mYiWqoE28PnNdrSmuACBj6mrTr4w/yIvEqdNdW/Y0ixWvQMsyxry1fpzjx@6ojTnytK83JTXIIVXNrKpBT23TXV6fCeLPka6qNcz4D33CWVP1Vlub0vsJ1VBoKkoA8An1wxwAtfke1aQeEX2IGvNHmWUBwh8zTkyaTkNRkSYDFL@evZQh@RNR5gLi9MLBDnrgaYkLKIhYPRf9Cux2zAwMeuk2B3srU7RCuSPSbHbrNAUAlZ3YWigJois/RmmBcJCcP6IGTffNyMD1tOZV8U@kMYSyWbKo6uh8AixfyBNlpNtW7QIESuEjtPueAFdnBEMbDqUQmIbmDb1wmgD6Uzzkebe8RILTk3q25bjZF/MHQGkAs5/mfftSGSrhdRT15TCNSz9HQlSvij86dNeZExRe6za9drp4NNVUmwpDrIZQtGZcXZc1zzEdNtR@P92SrjwM/p7qBQfEGnHAPr/GcW4o2bCvuc34iRUZEnp5TZ7raZ6050AQ7M/3PE6OhvmbIbSIDH5CrCkWysLJ5NSgjPjT1qcMglu5KaM4sPZssiw96w8GQ33El/KFqVE383ddE046umTRsuakq99S3JV8M20bcvOhSaTFPuTmwk4I3cdYz3tHkC@5soHN@yXnZLLXbVSz3eRfYVQ8GlzQqTl7R4x6WcLUrRoMm@T6clsbvd4G4e9M8x910UjW6PaKGPU4i3gB9mkiL@1ziPjKpM4TV5OYYZwd6X89SmCCprSBgyq1oVExjP@stak521Jjm3fGxc6b4hcL82HyHDSfJvLFrku@sifOZUSqzs9fmgdYNvZTal7V4qu1z3im@3Vn3iWsOKE0VxVuabAMzDZzqUC6h@uh2H4NjN9RCtpq47mHvSXbcte27lkkdGeU04ZahqTa2Y@0ucTm7sjRJE/c40W0SFd9uE7ZNmrDdi3uu@ZLAaA1wjfIORnuESOPLg7gA6@OchHEX0VrGFf7u1CN6xqXC7/N7tU9zc/UIGRXXiCXU1tzuo916iFNxnwvd5tPxYm6@Bi1trr@zajQ9GngsL9uqZtjskO73kQIUbNvm9/lc7KeaKutxWtzwu@dHczJlsoQzmXtHXcpa19By@W5ShtudFT60Oij5nedjJZ4nsSTpYYnlKkCGLjnPO0X9RdK6eIgTaAXEwhVon/Oefnae2HJW2O4uIAwVcFvJ/MJtinmKmUjyOZK7KsBq9a7ksfv8Ab3JXdR1exNzTAo16HcYoZAHx8DiSvYPSS1zf2rtx4mkW2hXHiqEr3IvNAU6L7rfqlKWEqWvjCGJ4uMFVEcbKkNlrnzaa54ruN/4nmHG4zMlOsVYcqaUk0A8nFD2oD45A8RH5Rr7bXy7V8DImgqN/EHtZq68M0EJN3FMvQ@OfXTcjtjVh@ZU5U4N0/SD@ynXM92WbbSnMokhXyuR8g/rUFM6va3Q766BDWQyZOM@cRgaG31QHnS@GAiiB0ikNjWFXalAKr57BTep2nNnBmgqhN@nkiKfieoxNWMyJ0OT2WmoXPXCjuM88ePkT@quQT0BFwpJHQowGOP9LqLPk6dNw9C@ppJArLZVOmKgxXH3@EOVdUvjcTYvscn0hY2TH83OXRMXvMtxBphAPRw7D@4ZLfsnpu4Z592aZL@n4/JNuT80xoROm@aCcDOQ476LN2kCRErkEyv3ti@ukBpNRZP5Y5TL3IevkEjfi89TQBxNl1bxcOWPr/VNlmGDM1LIHAOx1DYMU3pKX6HXe/R7uX0@tN3HnUAjA39zghNJWpa4I56pQrPX8T61ruhTjAaGDgOrgWx1FRyZaLiU7vjeJWrd1Y65xN3uy12Fn0C6TxZOZiZwVysfz02c8@coinxDVAui8f0i97MCNJwLZWy7z7kIX41bUJ/D/sMzazNtvIVzng826kRy7iLPA5qf3jN6ek/pWdQ4vLe7mgdw5ICfHbuvEJD/nmxf4DZekkeTgV3P9lNXMzTtMdRFecilo2F05uarhkdw2hD1q/CO5SYEOI8HZ@2g9yYiUTd@V9vpKUPokmxjYJhKnN7uAtVw3off75Ka7kz8Y2aPmpoh457wezR2oIH7fAzGlmE9ONnRlY2BadKjYWpDm240fxuno1Hz6mqTcvqYalcHfEMSZ06lazRbPfWhLDUVeaCrF0l34oa/3jsYdcQulVxl8Q30Tmgq0MoaJ7C6y/7wQ3xs31VnvqWbuaVfH1rW@GERML0ZxJtY5esB6LgrfWdRdk4wde64487dWXbPooSzhnsnN5HWjBpyXBFB/5DunPaZ2lzoyClaTLxDvZkpN2XGt372NfOVzk4QmrlTfXtdwH/ejMVdIm/LkWQwFAxvDbt25GHG7bVBe8LbXITVLh6btNnAMJitGVe@2WXocGTdecztf73VxvsWPLL3rngkks4aZ1wZ3jmlpammze8s3knNxXJ70f421Hj@8NapnrbS4YsS6HpIh@sbFp5cAWUh3rIUu4XT3ChnuWbERY5udEHexjU2AXZh5xbh9j6BeVrIdF8Wf7urdGXccbmj4uZLzb7dvQHm2S0Dj0H8eijb6uuhMVDm4pzdOvAYlK/krtramqoFF6FLXWd7Hn9MNQL0ul0RVz3VpgMErmN@w@FsRqvwc4ZcMzPp3kHW@2c/fBqQs9@YxbeZuy/Zc@BcPobLc9Oa1i@dBfg7BZ06oFlS5zm3nPO3Wdw3dXA17JtD23nMT502LPmni/sX5G9fqSAF4x9B6LKerA3mTyn7ZkxBc3J6wonzLn36vaoZXfY@LzJQtEDAoXp9B2OtQb@8Lw@gBehzmJXSf@QqJU5IxC1euI/ACEqaxVVdHdw/@TIYyDDicZ9YIK5U4XG35A7eE8@@FkP8aD5Vdu6V@NClj1sajGEegtp/9wCEsv5w1/LAWgt0lYY@HMTxiPB9XUTu3i6iyEb5nI8HWPh17dVxxGWFbq/Ft7k@oInZCozdhrY2nrjuXNqfw2EqWky4W8jejuEOAjaUjjzUBge4jPeYeFUTz@WQTN8w5g1W9sfQxXzViAd6iWF/Q2nh8t@j8rBrvAL1DPotE6Rq/0DBhfoZQXJ3ZIy6Y7RkDWjWflRyh4R@TqcwGSvLptKEutcmrvn6113IN@SBPI@YCs77dR4atBdxNaipWOfckMS9kLdzsKWMaJRxN/dwNSc@aLW4Ro3TaFONxjeyhryYBp@kvCcXVegGvnpon8Dd1VMdW7z1KBrvXfJdHUqbnwWz55H6QGka2sMyRVf5or5sqYqd3FH14Yj8WBz0svmjmBckOcQHZsloCODsrNEvZZsW2O8aGHGUElpYeXBJwN2v05OtloGLVo5jriribGwnowne8Vo75pxeAD/Vcs7h2QnXgEaQTnrQYVt3LzgL4hHgIY4pBoaVYAQXDsvRaCQS4JFwMbarA5gLRSYM8Hgzt45gMxDdA4JVO@z0lC1dj4piUbphZSYUBVavc6x40WHb2sgk@wMHPPrpklwvL4Xi8dBS6EwvMjHkgSsaaCdzweUp2I5KD57fCQmYLvPzPOh2S1zix7ftHplGgJF4G0b0xzrNpePsAD@EzE@4H@E2r7/587ZjMaKrQGH7KowQgCBoMMXoKz3j6ilP10kd5K6MFicQByiTGj//HF@vMtByYOjPDUUYV@x48yjvHD93rLPAyz4fGnq54JWL08x4yGnAK4/nxjuw4iTsxXILBX3qsK@zK7U96NkJED10fmloTfaCgwvB9IGFc0vtGNtmbQU32dCxNJpO1Qzjgo4QYE7@5s/5oXs6nOYcGnKTJ2MbvhTxDJpEJ91bLWMIuXaRfFIswwEJI5FBtRziQgVDbYP8I3hki6wBAEfG3bPwlAw/EL9ePWTxGguh4Rk8u1pSO@Gl6sHzN6divfwd6yeV//SjZOTaIZzwTbyQs4UYc0FKN8hY/uAsBE9CQ0xYGgk8Qe/knur0lVe8PoBEMmcyPLzn8phhmE6rIXsmZL7D40bnWGwY3VTP7qH4PplCIYZVrmh1iM616NhToo0R3YYGBq8RQs1bXXkpPOTz6fHDActCgmhYQAYXN55CZ9nwgDdGWRqxz6yHTAaCWMqK8MYJqaFNgX55zd1vmfbvg01uKM0hbQi7TCVS6TIVZ6lRXq2QC2S8gbY9Tr89G6XE@NlopVZP2i5Rz85G34ipt0B1w4JYT5LY8mq7G9dLiYr4@bMtj5kg3IRKfJsuiIml6/3t/drhUfXo@BBq4cYVP5v8NIUra5CL6MRUz9DIagrQBSX8V8gf7w3PMIfZksxW0UxYJBLwH8ohUIfWQlxY4k6faJqK/UD0efFtxRd@G8CRaR2VuRy1DV0H1iEwG1INCz800fYLc@I69iuIy1SU8diAPMLgZug5spRIJbAyECsOxHokqdjdhX3K/R5DsQex3E@2p3NBkGJeeqdeOC/iXBLc/EbKbUJH@euXm2O5v9wEc0@5AdTzdeNsVrd3jg9q09GAx@hJUrdcyDqn0bhwxpbG19hdgx10YNiJiGsRZYEJFIG/Op0Z2YBrKoMrBYrlCMdWn0cmDqX8C4EJYwJlymhIr17itAiHKQeog5SwWDOH5TrqyJdFt4/2obvmRfSEwKbgoXYznhAczEGyXpbAyy0GYnXI5Ta9fRLijrwO2X71J@a2OCwa9tFDm7e5O7oqr9exGfz7eiXXlaqzEXO6M6nO4iwFP03Ru1BgFzZS4n0UW@KEEJZ43gUvv2g5C/LUPpdpopD26zpHwaCX1mQTzfQ40LvGQCmyj0ODDj27wsTTL65wGkrmRuKoalsyloYOU@sDNLnj9luEb3vzsIzaGVfNSL77eW6oY0cFQD6TbTU89QbMxk/OceNPnOSGY2fI7SppC4Xt2BXxtASbXao2bbHASuigjqOBpMTSOAVHM4p03J1VNRt0kjZ039zoICknCTouws@MxHUmBIEnE57KGGNCAGHt8m27M9CVXsEoq/WBR14iOMJs@3CGVhfjcaBcV9Vds39FtANIKwNFNrCGuDerEroVxc1CkVzx3qCv@QDnWOA6U5Jffu@PudWtswG4f@q4R@IavP2O89YB9@@6IZIEb//Ue0vB28/427dJrLLbpoac5J15kTsP4QBfPhNulQllgmv7kMri1TbW9JvtfWbTKh3WZV8e@aoJJQzyHAzmgP/6wBSXVMcIzlOYVOEET/j0DbAI8BXwB6o3qNFQeopVD6PBmWIyiRnHqcQEnddQRnyJjuzPfByi3TVQwpK5bC4jJSGT8UsXIRkr6OKJAY4wEimCTAxcqmb5Q7OFR8KYYLdkTSnnSpw3kkvyt2nhg5fRJYAN8IHCKYM4eIrMiwFhFSdaeEmOShGMih1ZSAqhTGsbnNVAGwyTA0Ai6K27Z7JB3TQcUgEf68poQBrT2B0ANdHsJi4tKNz6nosoDog4brQONtscJ0cB8JSUr4Em/NUgnCDYIYIVhXnMevotOxuc6XXHShwDxvvFHNbVwf1P5piO45yF5htu2ywLz1ocw9KwZ4e6gRMLm5BbFk4lU@mklIv4OFRwUEF@sal/BpTQuEFYtBT13DDt6npt@8Xe/uEt21sEGZoFC7FQZTV6Fk/ETuueI@Tle5qoa5vJw1drmy4p/bmabKVCiMl@qtlszkttNqd3pH7Cz2DcTpsCbiUkiY9FTJsX4pu08/A29klo0ge4zreA30o1HLm@Oa2vVs704K3kP8@zRxhMLCNzgevMJmuEodlsYha33ZMlR2j@2E64hwdTwsTapnc2kr9PvO@2nuUZU56Y0HLPsATIVMLEnELijtMtUPZEkidFdo54xtz8gqxxsyphVicJtgK3tsP5c8Ocsty2@@wc9PSItMfnkFyrvTaHtEk481kmsmPn0cyDO3IxYtOfGF9yrA71IHea2gxcOQYy3GOynnGMhG1q6iAcCegOxOyB2duQ9r02jDwwuXw6Yt4JTxt1xlGClljCZHrxqh7gJqCYa6kpSsae9odAt33DZJNZtA3FdR2ATsU2hnzKXWEvhn2A69DjQMHeQgEtKw6RgZ4hNyunaN7IoUSi386GR5FETxm11S70OOFIDETTN5I0MRMlo50j0Kua80qA01JmT4YyYNWkV9HK0iiyWqDXSQH5HCS7mu@t1wOADKM2I0U@cxE61l1LiVjxRRaKeZRpRmKhBOMjKccIIu14pYmoBFvv4V5omvrodFRS2fzGV3hn3lGtfgJLBd0MZ6HneBLCzzVfZbHLRxn5VE6oelsZhdE4SrGOdAL/0NXJZSgi3GJxMhvmGIlqz9oPc2WhPHCE0sT21oy8KxQ8OTctGgoFNLCCZ4VhUAIpHg6sHXCCihDu9GWThYe0NdhmCUav4bOwHrMHVoTFK9hdXzGdRaM0pwEPCoAxC4J2yKWSpZsw2oENJ8tQSehr6218fFJNdiolEnVwUyIRtoTzmeugTeFMYCQAY1SIUiS0oF/AXxFzxI15Jxyj3kuUbIBsIDG07jYnmOQUrqaBfAFaUKlZ5YnPdsxEwHCqFgpFpzampX2BAV@szhGIgHaOFHfHCEBf5@gnUA1lNECtW0pbBXn57KWi6woQCHimj7bL5SEwmRWJuWb1YxP7tpRCkGdxyzlLChmdtntbC11ruEi1lCzR1FjpBtSaD2eo13QczWac/G@TiWTpOryklcdJ0DUjlfBSryxF08vR6JK@HF7SUdt68gRn1G6WQJlrJGCAOgKg@JIWKQE/g/JXXtJLS/JqeKldTi1TDHiFIfI1RPjOTiaul@Sb5NITUJZi4GNxoRNessl0mphISDeQP2whS8kY8Mw12gAjY/mY/JIajWIeEksNzMB3ybPDKHWbZ4dJmrwrOWOBZLfvNLcZVcyriVtG/jkBHe@i12FlscNy9gQ3XOCJ1dv0vLA71D@e8Es8RMFoG5hi@wdfwnTI4wWLI6dR5jpCJsxt1wEBR2EgIr7G5EgEhMmvfhWUcowJT3PpsBF9mhVL0VBWgmE6jK@Dz0APTy4LlnB9thG/ZEonlfsYP5U7iY/1/Yv9/beRszArsFBwfU@QMsK3@D2Dx10rLHXHxX74FQwuJwPB5LL0ZCWZ/PDhA4w44DqtJCogPvgVOY2H6qfhFcYqKyvLsVx@OfYs1PBlKxJOpSKHTFWT7Ew17XYbfkaPvmwRDvLr6VNKC4b/8M@4n5O@43BfEMTxDX4l3KWcDbKzFVlejmZSz/RSIiWm/uYvF29i1/uN1b/5rX5SWcTHHj5@evMK3YdS9pvFxW/W1jKZGBCSu/ff77@rVquZjVh2/zT7NBMXF1f/@j8sLqZSq6nkYt22pXro9OKtkBIzQuJv/jS0v/@6YdtAiAJeaSaBE@95@Eksm2UX7BNcFx2G/@T@1Pa5ZXQ3O5/QXh2MV8okbEKhbDp0@G1ofrUtMqnydOU//3zvY3AQrKSSJxY8B8GPwVw@yJ3ggLe0@3YZrARXESx3Exwny@UyOFf@87@F@JUXgAdDxqtwq2RdXLlxsBIvU5TPwUoOHFIqBen@Xz/6USBYGQU/BSVJCo7pr4FuuPJPpCcMHUlhJS8YxjP8TAleI981KUVSklJnbn36qhur1vPuAW6oV2b4/Lx697iKOdxAjsfCVeBWw@tv/4@//YO//Tn9/QH9/j1@kCG3@OzDBmMK9MB4FYvPbtXDzsz7QSIOV8JrHUF8jTslC@bLsQbPlcfCQZ9jhg7enTkk8d6/Ei4QdA2Qoxyqs1f6pC7OglI@s/dsqoJGDxgwC3oXc5LxSOolzmb93MrwXpgrC9jXwAWC37FX/NJ1@Ief@4o@6PEK/XR@0zmEC@N5cx9kh6dwLcIf/cPlveJ9kXwcbwK5fS3@GtI3EDwNntbrWzr@NT/i384n/Ps4wL@jFv4dfMS/o0/4dzDAv30b/1418c9fM4Hg6upqMBo9AJXRYdrHXMfwSyQazpvHvMFA8Dd6sQA0h3o0fnNzmvh2FC2VnH/Qo0reG17cBTmq38Tjq99WotFTytlpxcniajyzl9tjz@oVnmu6JxrfrgL26OrpatlYp1@iUYErXv@2cro6jYGQ1CvPnkWxwT4DBJX66WkgeI11UsbbMjvtjzp1MvdTjp9KuWw9jhx4PupAe7IRJCUIyWV0fEa5Dx15IRBEHbjAVeECeXz48v3/hr@zL9//6wJ9vghDAsjh4ejT6FNREy9F6UK6eGXsTf739kYQoI7Ec8MSe2JPaoNQZaJyLI7F8UjsG3tSG5wK/Il9cKpiZyR2RV3UJWk8mkJ1939/zxi82jMAmwExByNxgIjFDjy7e3uvAF8H0j6HP1UUxRFkciRewr@ooYgnU530/LYROQucMuGDAgpEQgolxFAiFwqp9WzO/CjEQo2z01C9FEzaZ2dJrlqxVKZEJlpvbhqN2u5Go5FEZluKPovGn8FVrkRXncfTYKX09KwYxzp2azuYXH16VknH0Z2LQgWm0C/6ldcEIzwri2cBGCuenODv5OryirvIga6zE7oaPPjkJMm9rk6c6wqu5OUdCKYcDLTUf6D/9t5/Wf@vjln4tB4BTr@@gYEvXRH8i0Sub65vnHslEg47L@FV@EMPeMc41zcVdBLQNbhOw5F65OaG@8E9HFnlCCuYyGqFIk8AoTUHeapnoRJjMKwKOytyZ2cjUYyUmuDjzc3Ln2lxJ1KibS9LTVyQg6GEtBwhkGymVMo47pV8qZR33FIuVyote1AivDhOAFJsuVVCRi8FzQjmgbN/WMQZGbKDHQo7RtOfmiYMC6WC@Pmz59VotFWr0UD/9OfPZ9CSQrjrpVzIgo@Y//wZml8oAkPGXcNZby3AAFBKpiboe7ItDwZW@JNqxs5CuJvQPgtFMDwligiM8Vl2dTWXqVRyGXDn8pFISVjiW2bC3WhBitwsJQVeDBjMhYJOkJRfiZDvTQjDWXCVPa0Ai9t4seubIFGbZbKRcHOsRDwPqVDgPiyTC@ejBeevvBhhycoyc/5OT9PRzPLK8rN6faKZoJQoXctl6aZ8LRdxguGm1HKMUOPOb/nJk3QByJIXS2eBRmOjelRt4FeScPEaZS56krwJ4MKkaYVOaTYoW6ifYkHqZ6FQsfSM12s@y4KhkgMXD4HkYvkClTcIQ061g0c@RoAV8QaCRWk5lV5MZkff5GoiDJWW8To9Pc2n8tFlkGvLhUK9XiffVR6DLQdNJq2kg8sBk/YarYisjcu1Fk6hLYIn1B1r4sq6rWiaa9z7yrC09pXaVhYDwf2d6nrtKJZaha4ptVldj6UOj9eCEr5mJ@8UnMb3g1p1Y@8YIuzv1KqHtefbb2rH@@CPpoDh6u/LylBpKFfD4RW@NxS61lVbPj@XTbNhwjXqcDGH15df/OTLL/67L3/ysy9/8pMvf/IHv/z@D34Cvz@H38/482f/ppDF@y@//6d/9uVf/Al4/nv4/Tv4/eUvv//DH/Efvf8V/P6jz@@vnJ8Pjv8CgOt3fvn9z//0l9//7h/B7587vz@6/fu9v5z/@4Mf3/3DeD//s/thfvZv4fe/clwu7M/@BffD5y34f8HhfvePvvz@/87//9r5Q@effPn9v8Kb8/I//NFf/8cvv/V/plL5v/5XX37ysy8//vmXH//Wlx//9MuP/3Hqyx/@K0n03/4MOOnv/@IX@P/zv/j7f/cL/P9f/uXf/8X/@Pe/8z@T44@54//@5/@G3//ut37ydz/@Z3/3W9/fcf/JvffvH@H//T@Az@Pz@Rg8jynX1/p8/4Py8@tQY5IK8AAZA2cp0KvWxgorsYDIROcGDeYP/smXP/xt4MPfB0h4@@/hDf75CwT91HvxQqI0cI1HJ54/ZexzEhQ@8dlnDxRQ/k/oC97s8zQ28hVd319@/8/@FL2nYH/bj0GUbsMuIbCX2k@xIXkZ88P@FJvil1/86Muf/uMvv/jjL7/4HRSv8UwhVo3FpQfmvwAw@wg4BMw9Bg4ApVXcCrDIFgMpcCyu4nxNQIp@@ABkXQQXjC@WA9k0vAXrdRyhVM5Ok5Wz5FmFX3V4TyQr6JNIniUxPJGE4UmDfQMDO/w9e7bMvonH@XPiF5AqhBryGIV@SYJR4DKffonimB5@o0CmAG84IROF7jTKg6IQtBZl5XI5GhiVIYxA4RXjjFglj9MDOKAsA16MxOPEGnnQ0NlojbBAzHL0gDWWyyMeMYoeFcLAMEPodSBIKSGaL29AguXRBkNciDwa@ADPD@VKvjyqILrvKAuAI7oGSQJUGXM3qnwH72XCCfCB0cZ3kJV8ORqt5MGnTEWl1GINSlPKUuGo7FFG5UZ/GPbD4@kzxr4RpLzAR7xQM8yBxnt0Av2UJn6eQvhZdNkpDv27TvotY3yo9hHRh/vx8KfoTfEdAMAbj@MuNPhBNQLAMwgecVRRShYeUY4BKBd1pmU8D1JmooEo1W@UXiB9yMPjrtWK7wXRYXGWlpbAtVoR0sIejIuYdVG0B7KFizSk7xWZkCsI6I2bepSlfRo5LW8sw12C/9oibczl5FgOLIVw6BxibhrxaNrIGEHKvVs0Kssy5TxKcIHgxJ/r6rTSBkp2hkUCYfqqRwRL31JME56v7O6aMQJ9OiYIMSnH59IjzgD9nVEslr@TMisBeNL7ED8o4nzaAqoBP96ZwMaKBK1cx1ep4YIT1LJcoFJxVguZFKgc1o4gwtEek1JigoESfp1ZSWWymWwqnctlV1JSJlfI5LL5NAi9nJhNpaRCJlPIF1ZuKEvPQHDEisvN7GrlH926/pt/NO@a74tXoPKWjRIsfhOojOLxZIpyXJayK6VxGfJBXoEKTVzw4cb4Oo6bRANntCntGvc/QbYC13Fk0wW4WGAhwBbACy5Ai@skzFm8394rOauY@K0pvpIpSFlghEjgDBiBYwuY864AVt4TkDhPJO7M5iZOEZ1HeEh0F9KBqtDZDu4aHRjsyOC7E9eUVmDVOd5YCQRo6ecUCFsP4PdQTuuB1aQXOh/Teo9/HXbdMkBn/@Ewa7J@wYM2VH6wzQvaktHcnN1XB707II7NPp4EUqx/MAy1fhMyiFO8HGANbpZmGPMAVtjx/h2lfOUdOsc1VDp1DuAH28@3jnzPo1p1fSuQY2t7uxszj6wDlGU7tc0j73WFh7pRsx6Kd7WdndlX54HjrkWWXYnFQEbCDZ8xuuiZWPrWBZESd/fFXWBk6KOSq2ypw3B0nYWmD8PAckUedWD4qCSSDYU1ymunwXo@k13JiZ9zUkEqrOwO@0OkAusO89t7QlF4yo6LiyULJZ/dkgdyLLNS6oxZDo0og8SMoTDCjXUFiR8QUe3AFozp@vjFE7QNNgjgObk2bq7AsXoTvwc5NNmdnvBAL3RaarcHQvDKcAECTVlm8PvaC@Ir/mtwv8eAp0F@t0K0OeC4lKh2mBhI0BxfqpDP5gvpVD6WLwBxpVw2G5NSMWklv1IQY5Io5aVcPluQYvlMIZ0BcQmh2cJKIAhiRe0kk9AbSIJAT1VvoaHpVbTYbSR6lUCQT5FAFxyWoa@PsKAcbHi@wzwT0vkzESIL@N0Ye0D7h5fVsoDfGhfxS96AWmYtFtzcXBc3NwVhDV9wTnNdFIQ2vmTzoriyJggKhayDbE8JgsHjQBCADfiLKK6tC8KQI8Bz9ILQw5daDvVaQVDxZb26uYnpnONLCuMD2AUP4S@a@7ICYDq@pNOkGAvCRw8dwFV5QhnKaQ1fME0M2eQh6xAmCM/d/IgiYDjgcBzDllvWalUQtvlLtYohL6jgWZ7Vl/hSpUsQLHgBbhSELji6lqLogtAEJ/KkILTA1RrL4IfmvfHItT6QBWHMCYQkEoQRQcutCwE0Lscfk9na2pJ7g7bS5dfY4s8WZA1C1NGwttl8/rzZ7TatcbX2/ABDXrzYks/HQ6vZbTrRmg24DIgDIRf98ewFedxuNGRtbshLCNFnQhrjhoJ5a8gfIU/O1cVE@o0XEPICQkZzLo4Nrj6ANvFa68NzTW5SiHtRCD1HzaZQQkYdjE0FJ5Ww8dA2rFhfbllGCd9H5cVQOBQbn6bqJfJl/XDkWizdYGAnTF@xQkkZuR6fjspiHZRwqYRzW@HF/lMB5J5QXJSfhkfozoE4k1IZIVJcXB6Fz2KNyFMhBWpwET8HZnRCLBSXng7zQm5FKC7DU3gqpME5CoshkTG4xSKnK/WnwgoiFZ4@jQunEr4CjBzPYArgElYKQqR0A6QYQF/VHA6URiMcvlLki0gEc4tKBWUbp8sj13zb2ZjKqpY64VFsVObZYeNICQtjKYMh9FXiLZxtPGo@xM/ncMxdIMzoqVik0kNm8piPZDKyiuIJBQo8Pziz9t70/cnJHCe/EqwY59/akvK5SAK3tDeMToM@acI@@CFRkzzBkyd06tTdokRKtF0MHKG6SZ9AZmjEoolft6PDwTCO4dZ0GB/FSyuFQKDi6F94CD2xiV/HNKwEfm9vUPKH8LPTrteRMhokthTcW9Ry/db5kc9EbYRf/1UN3Q04HING0U9s7yWOdVvuKKXr@En8hs4s4@FRPJKvtplcroBLbocpbSZHrqgYjUql3Cj3lb45GMMIhpToihcXek@2xjgkHkNxd@JDRwulE0s6GqChfndpFBwFKm08ab9WXrseFosAe1NSyvTVTyEolDpP9fKQMrivWHhoZHsP@nIFT2e0eh/Oagi3DoS8volXLAalczOxbXPieOcAKD/XmB8noFEWb0rd8in6f8bbalwQ6vH46ec6qNZlsTQOymV72OSfaRKboPvnSiPwk1YyJQ1Iw0/qLNF@PbnUY81y89tRySqbQ0spEfhnDfrFRqIB7fE0lUrFUmIhlpKg94NeEYLhtwLvGfhJ8INwaaW@uBjWwgJjQkwciQkpJilSbGDUdCCqWCwibaFS6BWeciSaWtbCbYPJq3GqI2iMJcwACIQeM9VYLwyxDhRZ4@CR6MenuTjLZFmk9BFIYC2F24m1yNNMqR1eY40IeEAXDr8Uy2VK/ioNR0qdMgt/GymFFyNlW/nIBxlURHMRiMmHG0v2sH8qLuak2HW8Eb/RZHuwJK2kiqfDpdO4BKUTP3dXhfcVoQ6kvgnAyMQ/gw/aQQn83IbK9YmJRjDxM0ugAGoKVIxUSJUckIDpSA2gXxg/Rsn3r4VDoZVUKBQJlQBqEbxJ@kSuSUSEQIKFnkggt6CvLgqFFIRPhM2tHPAhVU4KBG8CbdU2WaYQCF4Hbq5vVis@1fMlG4/laNx9fcJYNwrj6yStOiYaQbZIrniiQpML1XK1e1AtOdDVdRoIJ307BdgZPyUZTy5@7UJndLXyLX@e4fo3pAm6aNPQTlndWY1NpQNB@zrASUibCJKr0UryLCAI2ASdZatwPhtxBujfBckeMFu/dj/cW3yFo0QWlou8cZ3WI9/tqtp1Ph2v8D17LPgdFB@3x1SS3wWBmW5uiKzO5pRAUDfcfSowQhyAKAPpnc0KOJxXmHlY@Hbl2/y3r473jvc22TOxmC/mOW3OnsViUkgKrbJnoECqBzXI5GdmZKXv9BelYNEMpTOhtH9YcFYOjsoZr1hSpRKXVlPsKTAfK4K46Ei5uPi5wjmpQgG5FIR8@e0/yoxW8/CeAq2syKTV1dRyqkIeqSx4pFIrkeCX7/81nnhOrbguKbcSrAd5WhkAqPN9pikpWEk63tKKFAnacf4G2cgG7cLnYErMB4L5Vx8@M7YKo45Ku9tVU@RKuqyxdM0vdn37iiZv@92s3sB/5eZ0dfWGpjtuHAfebm548NQ/PSbXHTCT8Pq3jW8bxe/iq/x/FW6L63u8mEIuK7BI8APIIdvGhbNCEGeyQjBCCzGgIDOVKIhf6L9OPdaUSjelumma35omDDKWdfpT7GX8m7wv27a9uuy9KhjIshWJwaAkmfzy23@YSuX@n//we2eR1yCFC4VCTkoFf3X7Si4vBNjyQpWFuIk/3oWjKV/vdF5o6uOaOHe1vBDfONxbf1k7wj5c0fGj82x9bzeBQfhd9MnxypamyJY2dj6MPkYo7PqP1veZYbHjjX2Kc0IHa8mXpqicVJa220XnE2axSyYl0riEm02KmaSUZVK@KK4UUzkmg0y00ZCG41rCqIyKtW6YYz6YDK9HKPJCFWEwbEeF4b6tFNnz/R2KQUJneWGj9mqP7e3uvEu4vtz/aGv7kB3ubR6dVA9qUI5XtUMmVA/Z9qHATraPtvaOj1h19x2D4IPq7tF27RARJAMoT1HJ5QTzRnZs1R7bSdSAbRreTXnbRutCGUz7y5YpJ9E29bS3jl@rUvBTL9P@Q12FsaN/5HhYXeB6I0P0crttBfBEr9piCzhWXFgGDQQPFPdEe4Vlh28/iVZ2kbUyu6EV1hJ39fTqCtNE549pmX76gC0uLp7pgtcZ@YvhDVz9XngWBPwmedp@X1sI5zJsGQapqUxkErK7t78gum8LJwdHC5IXdrCxkPJetjcX0t5LDd4y3tvmycZC1ntbq75cyE2i7a4vrHhvG7X1hbz3Bky6UJjg3N1YkMSAS6xLUBIX6POt4c3tnRpbBqBIaSoUJw7RMeMNhAiDYsfNqyDJ2fLyVc@I0finOZ6BbisPQbvgU1ALqFqeIl3rMbZsmHADpRWAIVrAG4PIVrcVc7CidTfovALXgQUs0AIWCOAX8GA/wrHFMkvx79N3@G6SMLf2GWPCsU3Hd7@x2SoODyrADDEyF0fHuCGG4nzHGb9mz1GGOzS52qG96QQqQU4FS4hE8Ozn7vHODk/MJI04LBAk4@rxHJyGCdigiHDHooMvrxxeLVQXSKsFR8PBb00HbqZqMzBbm0gKKOfCQgsQTFP3UtZiDDW8GO5gQLz4ws@UADAEg1sEFz/0Gg63sKxdZdCiDEWQmLW9TV5C3ANRZtO1HGGYKFGKgvlplc@fmft2Nph@taZf9RDH7SDn2eL4eE7LCBtBvwX3tDFBkGUFirmAHBONQmwoDoX5yrUARIcfN8Tg5rICCYkh9uQJ5WMV3gohSgLjRSlFFkcQROAQjMiHyLysLVJ2IwvJZdyGRJuSyCIx9iPcVHRz7BmRAck6m9GZWvVaoVedCzqMnEszAtkJ6rSxrsGdTjXgHcUjcHKMNaGZxJgbKOUwEEeTMabEWAe8Z2RqQ9WBcxVrIhNdVoDGSLW/u8FriFtMIn/uQSUGuVekCgNh8QSbLzH6wkLTUuSLkgsF8pCggG@RacJICA53f7yDDYq2zNsLsiXGfkzM7c2iy0c8NrCDw2lEVjRywXnFKS55ViZAt/A7yLD9lgE9Z0mOLBp1IDwuc8Bq03DxOIe7cfnygULUZkux@NWlQLF8ZylqjyzGr1cK6NYmLAKlABEfBrxRgKbbdG2m5qGAvpBQUGl@GAroQCe8BG18CsEj4kOXO4kf//r40EkXZ5sytFuoQS4VeJTp19b0a3v6FZsv@MhsdZWlMjCiaqJLyoELjR2wPDjaXFZOR@xMv9JkU5kpbpyOJ4F5CsBzKCo5GDLgbWGMEiRh4xdu5D5@Z63MqpuN7d3a0XQo4kvYDSfjvYGha5RGZBrMyRCG22F8iXg5CneQCFzfDO/zNGJEz8bh0UGt@ioG@Yuw1UkLmNUB4Oa0hKkS3LgpgK@utKA/bsdY@LDKliPsCeYsxpyJC3x5dBKaYSuA6s4U20MzRUmJHMR7n25JQWyRgTlJCWEWjrDPZ2fQpYorTOqbn9P9tL6SbrNxegWVXY7H00EcKe8KmF3eNLmygZBtbtm0ODexc1FkGSvNBkoPNO6RaN3GT@W6wb6NukX3SLZp0KDMLjE8AY@yxTFgA/3itGpzvxZJfSPyAfpiMwY/7M5pgjJK@jmyJ4W6ChbPS1v52rw8pNFO5yXO87JKid7Ow6@cSV0YLgVmjt2THSDDHJgynkx3AvdoKngfvaxAgE/m@MzBhQ38ttUgUiQzPihTGg00adxohG1F6wCzGkOrBV0@qsu2A4YXhiZ4IDUkdEwHOuRB/Wk6oK3iSXI0GAu9zgxCNNQC3mh8MkwpBgJezuyBYlKufNnAOTv87rs/QRhgT71DteIJT1@OI0VHK96UsT24yE6nLHhxHEO7F5vjDeL5tq/HpnPCPLaZE4aGGudFcS0PzAk7H/bn5QAEwx0hztnhOSG6sTcvAjeANQmon/oIeOoncL0ejsyvemhX0zXus2BG9D@yhopjjmt7z8eCoFw6HOir6@CGAkzbUvHjIbOIPOsFEDM8ivgMKXhsFZlwkmy3VHUWvYvJQUQngen7GGxUbPUA6zdSKh@J@RD6MLa5AeW7cDIfUsjhHCRBdki8706z2h5qZMFZvJP4CbQDordheDeJYJj3wGPoBBYr3wVeQBNuXojHzHOa3ARd8TbjkD8uAGD1S1PG7u6CdgshRfwE/XWTj39t8nFf@tgmf1DSZXY6nY961PdeBI9JGd0G/oMScnM9nVrkq0rs5xpFubiDfdEokS8ZboxkOlkPjSOBPJ5yi0Lo0eORQgJx@RF9hXyh6nNMJcyLPel/lsssLnlxuMSbtAaal/ZlPoBmVBoNtD/caJDhyUYDZ5YaDYGnQB0vdnj@TtdpbDwsAVpqw6DQsBCXhZgQj1cP17e346ouxPj3GMqCPTAspYH244QYLnqXBRJYDYTpKZpZFpz9irLNKLZwdxpVXxpQwIcTISCeyrZOiUwMCz@cXMtfJOMRRTJmEpsYO31EageUGtp1uC8li1sNdBNaJ8N2aCnQUlQUNPxLE8gPRocswEwZHsEpfScLPF2bZvpsNPfCs0SPBvo5dY12U3ZUGlXTbJ/gGkISbtktclo7TvUgggmncu4T9unLc4yM4rUVR8@i6aGEMDGI6mQs4ZTUx@@ugsbtyEw6tGnjSE5@Y@7cpI3TmDNZnQgWw8TCnwpoOwkqYN8w4e7ZTwK3Z0EJ3GhDCb1cUQduNKCEMTqOw7GlBC6ypgRPYG9hYry1L4/U/hAnbvwWOhxNbpIt7PKxJNTrU@C09OMURYiEhlawww7eSFQoClB0myw3zVpvQvh5Bpwi9cBtIUvmxjGbPtVhHtK5JqEisd9AJfkUMRTNtpMbiBsTmMCVEIorFesw@PTxjitiUH2e8TP4rCcigpLEvPiT/spnAKo8NbxAisDggWdmEoHPMvk/9krKfaToqSCTGvNDccVtTr5xq/GdGfdjcBW1SOCekdT/b8ZJ/ir5L3So9P/9oOjW0OcfeChzzxDmq0crv8FhwX9V6P@rQv8DFPrfmDZ/h0o@i/J2i59R1x9Uw79e/SKZN4Zuw@pe4tRb6ofoYb8hRWDlq/QAN9en0n26wMP9s4sm5e/Wf2AvHfhV8qidO9k0qtXqUV@yDp5Xu9Ve9QBtba2JO9GT88zaxtXa87V2dWOj@6K7vqu8zlczO@bLt/l3zzufPiqgvW/tvXj/STNbvcDbA/PqRNm/Sit5uzocftzeGg@21o7764fZdytXYk3LdtaUjxuavfHq6O3Lo@fZw@jVxxf7Lz71xb693xHlQj@99Sr3Zn18ogeyl@pxe3NH3esftmvHqf7OhvpuM7ou7hwWXkviTu3qfXr9KpoVk9vmy73nB8fnzdp77WB75117/aMh5z5eXJnbyXahs35@8Cawl34tbX3c2@vWUoXnW8mrjY7ZFlNbmpU9f3uwv3b8bqv3Uq71N7PHhbfn4/1c7/Xry8FutJs5yQ1f2ZmoXn39OvVSf355WTsINGXjyEorJ8Zryby62jcK/RXl5e5Wt//akvTkXvZN9LB/dLVRW9M@rozSx@9OXl9lDt8NX71@8X5PVA8PmzU5ZzbbqcPzo0yg1U9vRy@Pa8d5@Xn75HX/cnsr@24j@aqn7Fbb@9rF8@7We@Nwf2e7mraHurSzfqm9e947f3Wxsb6tGfsXml7NJLPaUfvd3l7g@IXa3FC23tovque9d8ns2kXmXbRtPj86/9S7eLF2eLyXT432x6Kxbh80tzqjjYNcKp9saR8PPnWMV9Lx62ju8vxFSn1X/TQIpD@Ns4Ud7Z3S119EW933o49aMnosSevvtz@9e3e4dWk1q/rxxzebB@fWq7a@Z@@JBy9evmpqF/nBuflePzyUWuJz5eJVVJQDo@MtG@pIOZKzK0f9ndfmaMP4eLD93s59il6eXKSVjYuDN9WPB2LzSjff6taO2l8X23ty9Y0xqA1Hz1uFy@OLLW3n4579LvCqJmWzm0bHXuu8yRTeJp9HOxfP365JhyNxVz/oZHLW7pvXJ6pa6709/nTQym6@MfP9gd59/em4X4vWdka9T0pebGqH7y70wHH28GA/daW/VPuDza2DV7nBnrjzZr@9NZaqrxXpSl9ZH2c3RlYufbLx1np3saWbyXfqx@G@qFxG2@/MQea12uy03qit/svA4Yve8e7@m6vtbM563tfVtf28uLuztb7bbWdejrdfDWs7zfP28@23ylvzKHeRqq2d5DbeHqYHRxcvB4XWZT@9n48eaf1B9zgaeDHsDVf2T6yPb0bvM9V@U0kfaO@M8YrUX39hpkZvqrW9T92LfdPYlTZT4@TxjnGhiZ@Orj5t2bnqOJofHQ/6xuBIGmWl14H01Sdz8MJ88fpwb@3F3vsXckZVT@TzwzdtMX2cT6o9K72dyz2Xapud/sd@QZE@bbxKy@l@L2rvXCTb6@3jNycX2nn/Zf@8FcgX7Nba9vuhbNSaKUl8t9apZZWdtZ0jSTnuvjzMbOyK@2/b@8cfR0ft9bfD4zd7qlg7f1HY6WbeHrwpvFx5f2QfySfG25fWbmCUTxu2lCtkr9KHhfxezzpMn5wXBu9fnufWtJOm9GI71Vc2Vettfpy/MD/1rrpXh4rY7D7f@CgfdGogSY/3RTk7vNgdHQbSb476lyvmWvTdRevlW13S8ifqSvLo43nhotd7ebXRypxUP32Us8/PlcLhZrKpbWafRw/WX@@fdzdOPuUzbXFt5438dlTrDd4FXm@pG@eFk4u90Vh6vXk47ldFXcteHp5kL4@MtcOTrcN871XT6jS3znsgG/rj4/Or4eWWstIbXeVf9s7fyOLO2/y6bmf2xcALZbvfPjh6@bYa7aSUwuBy792ueZI/GWVf5Y2TgrGXV19WO89Hr/c6NXHFVE@ORse1XnJtXe3nQabsa8fW@t7rrfcnL0wxkNJza5/WjezKx@jl6F3uJLkf3Rm@ax2l@ieWtfVWtTbfXu6/fXlY3Y5uN8fP9y/kvXe17OHu@rr9Irqp5pTxVvrKrq6ntY4RsPtro92RZRbS7y92utATGO1C@/lR@kS3q9XO1Xb@sFatPreb2y/k0eh5ZwX6CLxqJ2@McuBX3I5igJtQ5A@Zm2IJ9O1u0xiBvORHHwN0di1AZ9cC/LQabdfmm5x/lVwOHPkPaeARPce4/bAJyhprG6g8JNi2Z@wYv3USY30DoqvoahkmPRGtcxyljQM@De40X4WHK@mbq8rI1AwVPyOFn7TAMak1@TxiIrCns/4Yx5sDpc@Pjqj4JSjHNjF9BYN/cItsowYWWi3mfpk2QZZ3ve/UfgAFwtS7cTK13GXxeKujyV0bHFqbXB8Ch96nADAFTZVx8gOTkHYasiRmna2p9DVJzNwRfsBq9znDT/XhNlh3xCGDMjEmCzU4SUVWahT8eqWtXiramD6aorQTAb7j81G7IP1@uIN82o/sw87sDQV1Q7FmNoCaPKK70ppcfoZWgp4tJ50lVlSGGrLVVAf4bfQGP8HR4Cm6e97M6b2HdPLZWaDlihFqNmRZmTv78gjfZmIhxWgX@@QAIu6ngxRBRXV3Gy4vm4SS9l0x/uLDvGzejVvtd39TqKdwt1VlCq8BtBoCrWhB@taa/Tc2bXL0gEoBvlhfe7t91HC@rMO3GE6d@rpjx6WPyiX3zSzxEvjy7@T89rZM3GEA2cdpR26YHIp6aXBeFmjfI26PhNrGEfZkt2UCuIZ2GiA2k3ajnGbqfAehSFv3XIJ7cZ5wTnjiy9WTCUEXnA0VHg88Mh7foMlBbpcXEXcsRSEA2s3pHlOZ2ez3G@a9O2qmqcn6BbpKfKssjBeslq@y6JshvnLgVJZXFmf/JD/vB@WGqN422ElGBcurFgJwNsS61XysY3Om/fYYh9ewlzTOj2Ea3qhL04xWeBK87G654WWLuClx@Jmk9nAmsYM7aw1rzBPC6ZlwqQQguE@HZIKiu7tVfaUuT6iB6GhTjy8XwLcl1wvNLCiTfMbY/bnlSS0SO9AOoPlZ5ZuBEOrUy1adJ3W3LAR6R/yFmYo6IY67hQicyWU2MEwgQsfhOOjGiEf47tRbVOE7vTwuYpxOp2Id/tlT/0uRb9zFBoUH@hmKkAg2Yxyhz2TOyzSCVrymg0lNWI8qCndwYxWqxItMhRE@@jM1Gp2qJx/yUxXpJrEoUTs8JxTEkFcih/QO7QmG9sRBbfCtuKzDd3BxWgdmSLQKCX3@7DUYePW4cd89Wwoswc@OGsxGBuecyduyQ9CS@@42Qs9NIROieFL15vZeejpYCwNw48pUR4oWBoHZwC8GmQy8nC1LpskdBOFtXwJvrGzKuyOvFhfDEOuU4JL5OnvCwtLqanglHiavb/KRiNcYnegpX3RfZBDSlQoLp5bDaTdyBiMDyvQ0gsx8BCmOILMcllwEKQeBlAUMXMUgJN@wPOfaacR5H2IPb30aBr87NCf15VRUqq@u5nGPp89zJnJqftaX09EUROaoF6LTIRwtD/D516dLBMjTKV8/4kORiaYBBU86Oh0wSXUmwEvUn2amPrdz@o0pL@45Dbfzoej4@VPFOs1jeZFT@aZ0k4HbHFiOJ36CzqQP0U38OEsvI5uDjkBNElLrKXhoKsY/ROh0WkC/0kyv6DscQRAoBogILh41xs7v6@uaX9/ZIXCHJvh4mWNMirE8DENAooDEyENkECFEA7XbaPVNDw664nyE7/jmHRglsosrznh@AOoJ1X43JRJjnHy4wg34nA/BUR/C6RuGCI2d7TV8vKkd4I7Z7d3nUIULWI4Ym9zdYi5yjF4R12Wdf5xGHaiQBZBtfEDjlJVX1XT66Omm72BzkTvws9h5RCodQjAe2dEOiS/UQUM1HGyclC4fKQOiI30rzQPIR0owzmBXCpM1JMeYf@M5zz@pRofeKDaRChxeRCeDSCGk2dFBdfdwc@/gFVFuv1Hd2d@qImYYYLZkq83ooz/YQHRd0Xin6tEzgN0vSGheJrnpfqFGRVscBMu/HsmJB4ANCmmQ72yOsLyc6W/Bc@95EUiieNCgVDTaijkHN@5d9cCcwthzEPJa5Ll2ukInT/N6QurwbveErhytoKQjWhqKrYcGwNj0ESRZ5/Ik6eJbg1EmfUGSWi7qUV3iF4t/Mi@dou9oIx/ZQxNXh5W24Ce/3GopNhlzmFAfUCpahxJxJIuPUOAzv/QT@cHPpnh9r4ODPiNKna7o6b0TNXdaWQTtkdPuB@m4PgWJY3F1pGtXrSS1yEmZf9Z7SnVUp1XGuxLjqZ3z1M4hNS5w2fmsQqbWT8@nFLF55FFd8pxz3djVzLh64m0lp5rrQKO3e2h0ieZCuNShCsNqIgsjxnhK1j1xq@yJ24onLXG@cne/UuYQdlojczqcSf/pDJjbbSBb@NbcBp1codHX0ML65y@6coUv1FPyg07uEIPgiVMaoE67cK74xDNUd3IGYgJpSKdlTp3k6tSpePjCDkIWd/MT8ekadArTmRVQdZAWk8NpTllJlTRsZ6Do80Sx6vTCVttt5AQ56cys9uyBLgRCX37gcHIqgR/j4wnl0UmfIC0TauSQic5KAVxXjcchQoTPa5BOA@IWy0DZUwfzi5G/XQyncK5OpvITMCjqHLfERQGCfoZxD/i6iZfmlttXDvcwHEaO@AomlpwTFO6J3uN9lpbSad/x372TXZbLTU4HozU3lkmJkyPHaNeN5QqBHzRPNplP4PyIDcepUGQr5BkcuoMuqGgaNGL@aKvY9WPe@LB4xB/jkqdcLfMRrO2IY6drsFl/aOMUJZNxhI5HK6WRlAgsgFCkOWDn66hu5w2A3aFsyfpA4WcsUZA7K7uYIEVEHVaxoFxNaBm4bQwlfh@t6tlDS@ETwODTNlq0SRJxUDyo6WGfdiPFUGG4VCw0A6AOnIP@CyRzHHbgoqHCmcD1dIVDxeUNTkJHJFCLxkkWTkbqlpF6fOrFcaVIXTnaESmXRzsSdWnuh5YxA0Reh1WIxtwdWHAIfKubofH4svO1ObdJesAT0T9vavB2J8MHp@443EHD@5jbI3@1Pmcyhrir5e@DRs4mJkJFZapH3DNwJAHcI1Atdx6CA9FjVKfuiXDx0ShSEMYvbZXPhTOSEaRFUC9FXYqFXIe7dBxbfhS84H1qnvi5DK0v4uwMGDsH5rzjkQ4EsnyEQzhnI2chsH1yiJEfB@SCN9Tl5GT/wQhxeOfdUHwTh7ijcHRHnHEBIuDjWlK7eP75mbT5pXDaKCXKj6TN5pSCIr62PB@MF9kBw9L5wCBTJI@WPfM4HOx4f3LuzQWk3NOE1H2Zn0rtsZl3krsFNEWJR2bdI8SNM1c3DylE7huXCl@kcrbVOGqmr364kgSV6DAC8Sy1e2eqwqGBKxV47pq@GFxnduO4koRCnEO/t0WOA@U5llPucWBXoHvTnJNzvfMKyjnZLapbTKpB@ty7pprUNU6X1WkW/rLGpduFXfEV1j1lPFVYJ5Jbztv2HXRwdDTjittfwA5FcE4uC9@0Y@ybNi6GOD7@Psqlxjz5N33W2dcgvy1PWqRXPi@vdGjWe@Ft1Vk7RNHu53eMh3hFt5Hj976pC5AQ3NBL7uZ6HmthwVFnQOmZipeKONPOHju7KDodkNe0VR/t9@6kXEwTjiEsZfYdx0Nd0CfFmgJ2wT6TnMcMRDzYjgol9cH6uMiRzFON1OUODIhGnf6sPDUbPDlAfScj@rE4stN3RPne@CRTbudijGG8m5yPw43idPeT9l/yZ2R8Z0aQHLRG5PR13poRN4lw8@uujE50N9PR3EDvMlNw@@goYo7@lhVdPSBsTvQFb3TAxwN@3cBRtF1lECe2QIGHsTE/Gh1jkPqd8BMLIx/5Ah8ezYOYZAHEH41MTfgFEs9hyjcsMn2DmNvZpNohipq8TqbzTRVJEyEedl6MJ@YpIkum4rgMyJ1R6VapptAxOuRMs3ElbvyDVFm0v07jVL/1D6z4ZSw8LllOxlkmHg52dzsQCrVvago/uSPtNKp7255pK9YbDMxiMqnYBnrZCcPqJq/UCzXJAQOHjtmquDLEdo5GqnhIo3YMXRkanBok2KHCNyug3otq2QcaTirDyAeMhBawdADudEDj1VsKfuJmcIX7BxwEdsKfWQiWbdDDDZ2NDaM5yb3snMzhGYhR3m3IfBcIM2wmIAPJljywlbGSxIjJpga3voxWtJMwJE9iCZN7urIDsQ@hSSiJc/lSDmz4MkYnp2dSJVt3gTjOHVHIAL8PT7tHcA5hgPsiWdOAuvH2pzqDBDKGaejamOloAqALmC4RGqQKJIWcdwXFpB23zqIObXlQaByREQs5Eva208NRPOy/EwkIy0YC/NvGRTzfYRvILpZCe1Mp@tSelpk9GbxhTm@i4OP8ab8WGud6eJ@Gt8UjmfTFNfTH7PuYt8eD7H8B2e/a@ZFM4vSoqcljJlzJZL@crWdWxFwRx1pqVyc2xNaCRnR8GrsyMvELwbgxAPtxN66mXCoaS2M1vlHtIQAeDoZQpEDQtORuX3YBw@kiw2R8NrpofD11on8SZBjatE8Hz02wyYgaT6YxJk2w0Qkup1dBYjreTr@gREBqwe0pbnk2DJMVwdFWmsMudQZ4LsuNgaej5FgTI8iRSrgZeQrPIjwh62QVG9oxNv6yZ78K9xMZKjuFZl5n7gKFUApQKaDpl3nuS2587DkQzLeiAx02X9WAHmGZNZzBKJ8lAGjsw8IczubznrR47oK0je09nLWhBPnmYjcEi8iNCUZKd@4pWWa@PSUgEtDeFDImmcBKJt2ZkVAVv/XsvqyFeCjNGoW5ezJFxHu9ZY8c7v6FDt99sko2wRgZFCVyRkrurnqpxG5cQNwDghoO7iyJh9ydA6hhWrg2M9mRAqQX3FHYfWh9GUg/AEkVh2yG/ZKvGHyDd53PdjkqyGywVHfXsMC/LJZcavBPw3v1P1nMesJrc4EKvkgfmr9mjjottPhCDK2SOAtMU3nFzsvhEeIOjsvp4sOcH8hjmhuc2USaNI15E6o8o3zOFYQF6pxx6lJibMS6OPvOh08xNnZe0R5/gBvdFmPjslTyLHMr@rB/jYORGI8yNGMIfMMUkPalAN6dEZ3FE/daN/QSJNZRkAdIUKDXqeuPUxvXYoxJNyVKuUUffOMiHvSI27w/dy/WmY74iqcwFKH/Ou8mit@0hdj/2963NbeRZOk9C78iBXU3AOFOXZokVNSN7GmtJVGmqOmZoNgYXApktUAUBgWIQFOc8PrusMMR6x3Pesd7CV9m7bBfbceuN8J@8HvPf9hfsP9gfL5zMrOyCgWS6u7pCTtaE9NEZZ48ec885@S5SH14MuAfTfNj7bAS1yaDaFs9X4RvivPKgo4OBXukLc114LcWzvPnwsliHyX6nUYfMJDDtjt4d2xj7IrGA5lqzz1ikNoLDzI88f8Fgle2BTuQAfymIsBqFYDEoSpD7HI@DzMdffNyGfnE1CXzZ@NNcNmm/FI@Zo/xS3kX/3nsJI/HoT2vtBclo5dCJdqLmzwEVj3lfKm73Lxv0N@l9qb6uzQetr8rxsP2d3k8v1Z/rcT4R9wRumL4D3gcsOz3iaMmaJsocor7ComN@Iba/nG69GyMgEup0hwnY7l0OB6HEdyzZ7dA6sxoBOc76VTnfaljk34Tg1wX8VFzvUFbDxEPopxs8UkIerHIvxGhU@4voieHItvWdzQnAPMGS/TtZzX1TRWU9FXiJpkj0fYPVcmZKuQEkW1vWL/YU05VLdtw7qjwYIoL296XlHw6OJyus/oitcYUwUCVVFaRGegOlEsXQVp2ET3q@nxMlsKoq8xSZhJRWmtXGkqIj538E@GSYqo777w1tfl0puXq0BOWj7Xy3nnZLHCZDJb0FsrmliZW7MmApW2PRRFbvdDSKZg9EQk/PZ6Es6NjBUdRoAEBKyrlgxDUPahLouoRlnUGXzWbRi2uGHffyo/r6tVYEZPP9vPYuc9eqMcg/LsLyJJFFlB0rgmtYXXtmqGdrsUi7Wt80lvgQxH0icQhrp7nzGnANtYDNeEZJHFU/R4vp4yKzSVWbVoKJN@ZThEbAJR1IF1A9@NiYzzDxAVBARgfX0ysXLOg2Y2VZey0llvnNvcpLZWs1jYyG8lmqOlGdn2I@hoXNE6kiGnZDTUHtaM12/5vYf5srfJ6TXz/JUuTKjWrssJwPjG5UI4mYgemeSeINgzPGrJSiQMnlM/DCXjDRSUT8ynkcby7OqfEezGrDLhyTTfnmPjZt1A0yizNL27HHZoqNh0AImoBk1bydob3MgS3Q@lnzI7awsIAR0zKwe@sNCPs4ZXZFF4eiUnY8/1@BJK1g7XC7SzCvEFvV/NK2A86R@AQiVM3R69pDsujmVs8DnpilfH4BZoy8X86CybCbKM1NZpL1vuhpfD42O@9YViEcIqxV4NRlYZtNK2GAxX9dNaZQOQQTlS5EOX0GS83zZ7WxEnTUfqAaiWAeeV5y0SIAwzyE64gU8vKyOsgqjFnHivrIKJIIdLxPLTMCGPryn4gNakpOq@sQIau56G20A0ixuOw3xU1mA1xFofjGvJwEiY7636BsOxe98SJYaKbzkcCSA7WZK6DUauhTCyGIl/j@iaWk@Zy8I0laFS1Argq0JbHcsbXDhoNZWLcEs87bBQUyy8om@XnRay3yMAMoGsx8TULgTKNUoUrWUbLV/Ey1lE4qrqYBWwZMcEBrHTV@fO@o/lTIIBGOHvogIH5OySMvQ6Eldx0zX3STudeYiHrrtA5cDIbTjsjP5xFw8VveyHkrnHMUk07U9KCP3@sP5PkONgw4c7qCAagntR3Wd0Nuglg1OnwXnu6iZz8vj5qMHEnob5n1VCbwUQVE3cIz0TFfeQ91Xm4HI1OQCoHLhMg6YGawJRtvCqiNkBHJ5uLjaY1LmcU7Dq96YwP0eMQyhXQKZ1BHgQdjwlMxHhKcGCjL0Aejv2JVEarbRHOlLmfab3Grj7pgIx9bQZUqb76GD/OZnQL614uEsID3A4qqBwe@U4ZOn6p4QTOsiNqt7neur6WUeByk9ctRCRFDVwt/QXuQGzg4gq/dm3yCgeZL6oE7lS5BtwK0GZzpGSiZ1@8rvn7kmH0U/pPTDIbWZeBlQWldfvxksBaFctiOcPABi1WtCgGHjQ17sHCgvYlgR4Eh9c9vLWI1gbLzjCLp7RA/M6kd0xdovkKsGCmEx6nftDnYSMeDmJv68o8UoQekZVKQkCPZidduKQZ8HhZM01@94CQnECKMeoS1xybXgZ8wgVlWs@voerJ8uN@ye4tqYr5EjA/BGjlSLhBdZtYfqkHBt@xZpMdnUFRf0IUsoZhwfeBToSbEu2Pfilr7dB4rrcs31orjbF5AcZSLDxLmYRB4DV1VJxOw8kbeTmC2I1P/mknYLk33gJFYRmFjEQPj/xRnCcvGUY4F4c14f2Mi@W4M71cyGtW05QOxaEY9IjhVDzA8obXipWWrTZyQ9YWHWE9kUDVdRY0o6SsvFzKwW4Xj3lzFRmi2AY1XNMtPdaeuxVkrrUoU@zaJsOBpq4Sa0ND6hUBaNNyiN@1SNLUUWU0DCWNFx6HG1/2DFhLmztV3ZRzsP/STjN8eq34o62G2Y2yPjxPVkdch1US7jmqujeNeYPokyWGn6MHezaAw9cbNz4xRJzaUnOt38WWVnPR8LqW4r@V9PgAJOm1a4v3GR0eC6smHsvk87ya9TZgvsMqA67J2khxeeZgHMjWzzBV0UqeEu6ArneFYArafIM@XWF4NC3Z53q9QaNpLZry2nFu@qqcPrS@s/ZdZxiF2pUZX6xSKOL3wvd7iTE7UKrX@647G6ApeOmnMrGByrJ1yvWBPXJYNVce/GWkGJz1DmfAIfu/5GgLGof6YrVCUGyyol/4dcEDIxMHeq1GPdAyMumButnW1eo@GBdG6AQ/eDvubJir@sHEP6I/ewFa1I8KoJfsy3ctty3CxBe7T57v7@y193Z@uLP3codLsiK/NSiejessKYtO4dx7pPEWooRDnNxnk4Ducdw4HGcJHPjLXjidqk@I3fWJHX/ToZKdmZ9b@ea@9nR13qvIn2xK@X0h5tn4njWNowAmQjOoKlH/ToUBl@fhYlSSxU93IDukgtbrEJ4MJC5UDmcmHeaSg/MTO6kbcrREhtCWDbhSwsH0FBSg5iaSb8x00wz7tJv9mtaxNdAQOcT@EqxDBBAAlA@t20WNI7W7e5UG3ieaE2Qk2ioRlon3ftxQL6Taba5WbUu/QEN2huHoKKe9JzgtYMqNLq0K4sBvmiFmoyCqAnoL8BSIkZYeSYfq4A/qzVqj/u25NIgfsX9H3gq@hkn@17TzXrbTz4yflGW2b2IAODTOecqGLhE2KdOCLjtaU9KgLlXRmq7o65mTr7Ym1@hv/Y4tyFcYkOvW3f5ujMa/XXvuK5tZf2MfC9@9GU7mAk5Y5Zjlm6liev7tGez8v2I18n7mIpdZUXxvOpFtOqEDqr2P8UThZoG1j0F5PNkVgT1ETVb8Exntbh3OKEWTmVMroWhrI9gklebjeDRaE/lqSvQJDfqEWvlvTR1@dV8zbAHi7marHb9Hrx3jiERHG@@lCW8D9Vyi4u5q658n2m/qddX2odI@WYD2jAVp2HO6uUkVaT5t3r1TCTVwsXQRHV9e/lrD3Jq3GKfyjjDOKKPru8PIzKRkSv1dhIIZpW2Qt6mOkSXhtZIh5vRqdW0SNVyjlVCI13xUyeA6Xx6/lNp6PIKxsJSdiLlCfN3W4k2MDQJR8d0A24NSeo4SKGNh7CqUyakxc7GqMr3RlmxC7Av8/y/WVnYJioHH90ZWv0Mjq@@tRr63GvneauQiq5Eb1@uzaFLvBqM6kWZDVT0l6j93gzbU9q767NOH@2r/0x31yavHf0f9ePeV@uzhc0rZVS9ePXr65LGi/@88f7mjuID990N/ApV7RVO/7fd8ls6vNRq3FWNeClB@W73snKhPw57/lhbPvahz8uBYPmojf7olpXbe@pNFKM9BYyizTLXVBMuK5K3JSJxgcd2llXyCd0TjyxNtZG@ekUiW2PaCw6FbA25522MahPW4@FnJGm0QfEiphKYjT7KsO42ndSZa@jWlB87@e@8RJKLw2Uv18Pk2In1uP9l/svv8pfpkd48@X/wYbnbU9hO4jXn0ClkM@Gx3@8knTx4/5ARpQKOmIFtjg/WLmlADOI9K781ghvBgQ3CF@ivh1ftGLjcKjVVEpAqzUey@p09LCu/u4uy0xS7aix883PvBD0HV@D9V@TyCXDoO1bUFwgcNGI1QbTqKdkucqYO0rDblQDpZqA@Q3cqxDIh/V5RBXuJ34sBX@ccQI@JBmuNmC8FmUFNF1wk3UBlHsJ7iCAyFQuUeo9yi2lh6YGqDYHVgPlD0gXbMCj7yhvHSGjFSBGd8MupJGF2TQOtetLq52ulEACAQ0gkCABkMEqadN/4TCEnUHQ0xm4Lxp4S7kvDFyfiTU1CNMHDVCY8kEMi6bpPMG08pAhx1gpHMY8KsSU4HjpHCRSKGh5Oc4dCIXFkljuh//caGV1mCzNMpOKCdbZiK@NmNVgOd7cedwTRSRa8EaTCxIP4oEE2to2GH2D2WC09gsPQWagRc7bqHf1vGUb0hODkQp2FhuguVbIctt60vfv@q5ajko6UaobfHnYbClI7/dGkDHi014OugIURV97yAW6HxlAlbRhMO9FIuRiGtSGL51M@SUY3C/qznJwpoXqf4RfDllyU9yJW4iKPiw62zGnYI9YCHkFP4oGI3F8TEsKbkMV6jZA6LyR7Eb8MnUIaYoIE/MYOra3OZB1Oj1sTRlYKeX1Frt8PGcJfWyitedIPt8TW2PqP4@TsSszx@JumCTbbcXAR/zlBigGenCdy8DBQUixZTbokEd8jFZ8fPVFQ/@Hzd29p@9Lr6s59UDuv1IzkWOn15vBClRHlmYZactofVnWRtQLPTNNJcNOuitNFnlNMSu9wgI8LlOCDi@0G7ZfNErLqcPuJ4Wcl0Tnz3zpNSVbY34SWESDLx6VZRB6bKCpc5VCWNID47qbHwrGtSKozTntcPENces9CiERnhHGH1GjesGuvXON6u8aBHJ0tO02ky3RZ/ycQi1yuK/xXd@ah/XnzklbdKdQPFm8kOZ9Ec0RWDuVnSvTrH9PJ9tYRu@2J0dH5fHd36ha2T6@G9sG1fiO292lYtr8Yl15KD6@pof3YBWrncvhZa6ntlNWK5JJex2ZVuF2flgxtmzV9S40@W5o73HqHB3YuIqhapU9tsNISHuKIIxalpXKDkookJopf72zt7eyq/AynbJpWlc68z6rF9KY5B4L5uPB2JHTIfdjVLNNkwQZZ4MinnYl6arPaizZw5eCuOCk2DVPR42MPCRu0lzmSurSPkZmESAobXciCakUu27sycQdGBRnx@AE0oFU@a08FcZjdvyOUjTvb5kInHrSK0cfQmGFtixp9rZ10sqp4sXESGEMZ10DnCy3f2/H0m9PGmqUcILP@nM@4wlPB78JevXlLFY7wU15IzeMG0mCllnRVepTfM2LFZXpLC/uYLysZiP9e0sHOsa@JYN03o4w@cSHZMnz7AO/9CZ/ZOtLzTHPGccs@d0FJ86RWTVxARmcQGqwfuqqDih@f6CuPRsPekZwlyd699wK05MK3kaGYad2s10IdEwd@5mz4e0lXRaXthVdVvpyq5JRI1OXG3lmswmYT57p07ty7Dne6FKV79prjlDkmfn9OT8duOgzJaRKwqRCv3yfOKyY8XwAVD5xEX2C@aDZMqSKROxp2S6DtfRm77qC2nE9jiUWN2X@1XIC9K11pS81TbsrHLjeRiZ5ClPjhb2HZUds3S6J9fXN0jDup2SX3X378@2WwAgjz8/DcSJnMvHOOoJEJ80havqMSSb0bQipuihAQftJ5@nRiYD0wcywOJN/dAXrhhIy01PpiGb6DXbyJn6thmeTxD1U4647N3EHC9Y5Gp5MEmQJcNKurBF6KjIpE1H/RDViIY2FCWD6SVyTQ65t@23eCbm1Af5DwBcB4wPTuAhY8KivieTUgVTKjJQlnSiD6xSVVJorU6Be9h029KOuwSgvFwYdPrkt73EXjOpt7TWE47NuJlYUtDpiNkFvIamGW1wWDR5mG32fclm8gYm/ShbgzxlsPQpl6XVOhUmaQDXXYWJx1KEnFSNumGhsLFFEzdtRT5/ps2T7KONkcICxU1CoaHNa0/db@oeceSNuGYykRSeX/Uz/GkcMxTi8pcCQ/gWlYvoYMHwWGNFSj1AQSeLJ5Y2UgPgriAC0zpTuhLWVRSjBuA/@pG6Ka6ixc1Hzz4Ait84ke9ma925uDxTWxEsyrZMcgNtfN8W@1@ovZ2X@wkUaPFbdAoXMoo7HEoZt0w7o7ZshWa8HA2PW5LovlM5576kmtQyLcFGoUTB0g@07mmAkZxiG2pzt7136kDurzHdlKK/dKhnnTTY9uHWi@cjaZn7@bveHrnROnVaAncV@c1CAnuLw2L3omawjbLgd/iEBYSdGXbuFWIa@EUrmWufXOE2uI6tedL5xpbzp6fNHW0M/mQjgNy0jGJkyAEybOp41vScPSO44Cb/JbtqWIx3TBcSrXaUnJZfWwDN/puxN1kZVespLyqko24EllhFk8tQhzRuLaS6ofqXfDOVBZfKrj619Pcjh1t@G7W0@hcMbztEjCNQydbXiWcPvdzyV9LG07PoErGG9WvG7IhEOQ9Ps09WeMJMF7fS2D2cDBgsoGW4HgXJABlmywBcvlljO3sVsZbL6NIdovj/bjcnBW1xOgyimTXEjc6ORXxXk/NRi8k6kwCkuBHmxhB537NnDlaNksVr9qsKl1QL0VmZ9pSZ1H@lDLqMMe0QNB6PDQ/m4dieqMKbrEL4ZMj4rZAd94ZEJxB7E4F15qb3kynu1eS2nKKpyGcRqWACWfqprp8LsSTSCLpFJZasq3YaEtHAwetpa9GOnIOHVBeQitAq0lQ2TUxLIEChKk43CwOqOzEJGg5G9RZ/AzvYk211dmNFrScDersjyWs1SysSdByGnTpXOODMjn2lqC9Wbx48kor6FgXnVOVP/d7s6ncNMZpBe2hKW0Pl9DS0P3gKJjeVzGhxb9q1B4s2tvr2iO2SSMG/87HlvThAobUdpugq40R4rRwaKkgo2IRR7nkW0yYW@IxAS8hrvE@7oAeMIQ7DUo8MOmGGCJDMzTmFjOkmDs0Umo@VS02RlJ5deOMPs9B/R7cOBN2RyK/5yv50nlemtVKnKLUJ5Os@aN798xY1KZhO1CZ/1q68YwjHKskjlqcdMG/BI7Z1KZCxFEZhj0RdlaAq2WYtQNKBwPODzspHHhNWe6LKUhoDi9vBx5UlnGgCWV1UadcHIapWsZx88o4DMO2jKN69XYwP5XVlw@vjEMYwSwc9SvjwApcHtP8jTNCcC7/zWcttcR4wCxKp3Yq3eTSsDg7ia9uui@GVVWwF2QMCfh56iurHZowd9f60GGDrjQeYDqWx6MYyE7aoquYT@6GCJibKFla2i/C3HKqSGCdnddSH0TTPl0EtcHQ7u@MzZ9i0VNCEo2Q5R5gYmq94wmxSJjNmuY@DAHCOKn97TZUs9ptlgy92Nv9wd7DZ@3nD5@BibohZxTEN9CWYXWdRm0N8exF2tJmnSJPQdUC3cjxOezkcfs0mh2@RThyLErdOHPgzvNCQKEmj@VFtZF/qj6hLA5av4QTkDUrm6HpKXIb7KGer77Nl2JI9wYzvdL82ha1hGFkneiWMIyTnHOYLSn/eiQaKq9Hr6cC2FUHYpMZHbrtfQ3DJaegUtW3r6c/9Cdd6JJUrdNSmUWo4IN3Y@dUULnQEvQYgzOBv6nX1SPjFFfbr3WGPbi8nQ3Y8e1JMOycdPud2vh4nBtEnnZPUywMIji5zEGZ6sn@zt7L9gvE6dp5zJYT@NfivP0nz3Z2X@0j5yVl3dLJO3t7u3ttVlDfe/ViHx5DU0l5F1BjicF0QgLo@e6nD586MPKd140Ug5CI@E36o135VFQwbs/5vws286iIKkSbg/CwmQqKclpFTYMTP5yZ4G3wP2Eu@AosT/AoQ3WZqMbskKYI8afOi32dnjtQ3I7JbDxlUNaAL6ZGopQsITAn0REKsC@iiOh21qaviUQZeTDkC8fFVFkYyKBYTtt3DSLeHdgmLxejXtGg0448K2f@iCDx2lSYTQfV9cJ5CV4lx6w0lC5cqNPNUWfnqIXsknoEtVZ6zgli5IpdWzlj8E5QbFHCkxBbpnABeUFsqXI5KJ3l3ABROotOVYkfdaYcG/okjI5fc82ZI3FrKnq@VD8WiP2lLXDsGpHPF@6jFC8w/T7FxhwHsDy3Y8Z/TWdFwly0s1Pk96nYrrsG7ZHH1OCH06I4emGfffG6089dugFtZKRnPJlH6PXbmO4wVyhrPJq2aKCmk4USC8JoaoeLen6I/861a9ceFGiKtOBKLmw@L7nijhJGQtFUAJjNy2/lN2M3NmKWYBWHBeKeC9HMgvjchVjLgnjrQtzKgvjq5wISDIrlspm8LbV2545oMyfmM6P4f7PFq1UDe8@oQseFCZ9b3NzGgmRHcGjosgdzUPfOJuRuy@5e2LIk6q/@O@F2celSVa5EGn5Bsy/A/Ou/n98UCd0VRunfSA@dAwrEiX7yEhNmyAsf6yVumqRtSdPY/vICbPm8mcXssn8cr4jPVyyar/4qAZO9bH5h5l3Z8TMvXNfiss3YqiGN4H8sI/DeB0Fbypv9xd5GxYAX2WubFovpQYxAQG65IGtpkKwq311YZcPF18yssumCNK5S5Vd/revU91cGxJ9ZCD5r9WBmgv6vxEZj1XwqlAUaCSRsal7Er74rwY@SbXCLZYG/iLFzkcOL2/3r30@3Oy6ZCf8PMhcnF3DXl5n2zIH/D1fFcWsljp8Iimp15bgVBKJcXgnx1a/idsjwprfZRZvk1//o8tKN1aX/Xlw6vua3zMUtVINBlj4CrXpQMpOLHlhsMn80ADYlozXONWr3nLPlcBdrg7FkB5o2W1ucJbPXTPYiM/uWzU4hPxcCy1BJ8K/HhNE9iTDIpFH8m618heAymVueS7WVpEMutSvEujYwp7GxNI42xXGInq0Uw3EzwWQso9a5JU3sneeYCm5lMj9RZ9I5HnUQoDUKRzUdASQI6zsn4RcBLqpJHW4ual9Eq7ihb0JaMwLm4zywrw@hUEFN1U5FRPdb@HYAdnq92clsiDc0T/NVcIxUr8NlHDOCo9lJpHHixn00C4bUAw@UWkwiEps3plbyLUyk9JWqT1WdVe1ylfW66I3X2A0dJ3HbepNgPOXKvGVeAC6fmEClKoJ7Dqwh4WGgfsaIxBWtp/vzNBj5RQceUVyDipPAfhHKnpRq8cpIj4mDowINkOezkwSGMz3jrBvjSU4tgsVPsVFZw8j5WDdq4iNCiLWOCCK1pn3QsWsZINEWRJMklrXK7ZKMEiN6QcvzJAlxu7LWQEVjZLGLIvYMbTXLOwN2W8RGrYyDsVlongWiCGP0ely3GtQ7yrDt8vJ/@@c//3f50lm9btI4pk4w6hDPwBFJYqz43A9fmG8HPfgTbauYwv3vY9yCuu/3gpMOItRMHdS0uFZgpgkE5jNaaHBaFQ7pvAmPio4vGFMhFla9/nB7W@1/urf7GayhRIjAqyBVHItgU@XLMuxcMpGvFYMBolfCMswzXTGATCOWoWyvAGZ7zO51BkVHA4tG6w/@CY8Wy/JDaLrLvkwhRHZenPpATgjdWhetnQizgjEPf/CPBXM4Fu3ZbMThOK8XJv0c@7T4jSiyuNQvgciu72/@5J9zddqihGg@yFVO3KpXEf2ce6AFsrxmq83Dlb1KVMODsBLxpUP0h3/ByCIJ0m0Owtw191S0SLK7/Wf/WjEOPD7Q7DklVQJP@VJEvxBE9vWAR24lvuql@P5I8PUDfgVwEXUXyS4@o3uyNoHRUNFJrl8yfH/zJ7rFBB9M8WZyQR03E83NZU7Gf3Vnlsvq6Vg1vw7@lTP8py5Sbea6CqNcVJl4fv7X8TZ1uymuk2V9X3N2Z6ppmR3@@f/MWn2sY067Bx7ABa07VZl7ZUWb/@W/svjnuWvzSxbM3/75L38V93G@smfzlf35Zbyb5su9mK9q@7XUkfQjXBn58nzlVPxVsprEzp17zucqBH@5atznycGer9rytPTtpp9fsu1XIfmFQWI3/PzSLb8K1x8ZXJmbPd2tFdt9vnKbG@wrNnoK/80VzaTN@F/czTi/aOZX7vnVy@LfMnIQfDAeXZqWel1TOA0mbe@pJv@FZ1783Uq3xj39IGqLCRePKCpCB64psfYANb/n7vyzdEz5c6Fr4tSmdrZgeuTU0tS1EGvSGUYZVXnet1bXGoaO2L2MWra@XiW583p95IvR/WzcB9fB73cnzHlM@PkPwQOyT8bf57kkapvYFbG2YfcEB9zkQ37BiZaWD9CxzyHDasADdJ/YDf57z3a32pQU5jeupbEMQyGJrrE4HazQSkZEcxLl5mEmUyF8auZG@E/2BBLuqivcFQZL95H9yMY5lx7ef/greyLZUQqT2FMoy5fj/I96GljFiN/K2WOHpulWo/YSX5aRSqaaK2Dl1f2f3dMiVd1qWtIBW4X5j/@pvej8CLqsfeoPTF7Z4z@CY2JgVt6AzvkpPxlBsXQzPjJW1vzPzMRHckKtqhw32RXqWVHNX/zDPJZ29iBJdutyJktjXMljqSfP1auXO3tq99X@i1f7EMi4jhEtD76a0RO2W85lZmCTQoIlXrZFbP6asLNOniyvoBKU10rc/X/xS3Rf0Ja9fCPvDNOF5f40Ua5pyl0wRjwVVx4hPT5L5UVoQa2TunVvPW9djxAx0E9GU@zXyKcfGkwEE@LwWd9tsvzFZNrlunXFgucKU/9tdssRxqwWJuCqwwR4TYX58xrfr4zvZmWwyGqB1zsv6zVP8FMvjMtPBv2uV1BCspkt8D09Pa0NEJ5qNglqfgT3RBEcw9XHR0QsjEIWasJtNi28oEe8LZwXznpv4l/VXmf0thNBQeb@HCrR3sZHC/mbWyUjHh@dSCiOrysnVoqlvZVFpVchZJVu701lcNpv6QwxDLYKJ5II6mdiPk4i8ysYDyxEOIWc3WZ1h2964ZCp3Xx3SBdZPq5aemggF@ZTf48DMYwxQuSF9n6qmGguiiKFwqMB59BPoqqMdXEwP1gcJorPbfGENkskETEvRCoKwcgXPQ4OGzCX/Hlcqan2YK6dxVsTMrw@QCnEQALNwsAkLMKRMxel@C28UCENkItEGix/eh6XNuMtXzSPnlkYtCbGNOB@sX7w@euD14ejyD@9eViuH1Xg6AjQXW3WyGPKPnvkN0Z/@HY4DqNE0siPpqLg0jBJvWO9GmStiOKLHquUxg01yyrcBPGgQTvQ40wc0Q@nxUCbqbI2zjE/b@cP8vEYS8MOdGMw0oFRMtBpeHhyTO1dRIcOIqTbLplIfFm6UPnPJvCnZWCrNOZwADNawIwQgRqSW0XHMFXnyVbhtUwSaNjFB26qKyafpuIgleV081zPv9v86@/d/AHti@zW84KVQzGlNDb36cD19XYRj5hbnjOv1IL6zc4QLv/yOyN2T2MUB0utm3VjmiL1oAs66Kwz@T3teEJeUkdaCwV1LcD7qoUn21L2hRlSq2kSv8JzvlkIurwcIBJBJKOYr4vN3WLE6crBwc9iWcVOnUbOuZFzKSLQ8xWNPNTFEMjTddtwCKdtHbqPCF9TNHqZLVRR5y3iU4kropt1W2d85vAqMBaGNKFYZ73DzNoPnEY7h1YKARbiEoK@P@jMhtPNXPrAa1btlz2jZCjNGSVfehnIWUELjI/gliiVFe0i0y8WEKUH7PaSfh3k8s1Ko9Lk/zXk//mKSTT/by4nNpKQzWRio5L6328l8RAjm80WNRu3cSDnfnNDjRfT43C0lruh7J2t@M6GP0J5Qf0ikvfhaBSMx/6UwxypI3@Ex20Efg1CSCzg/Atxdej3G5/9i2wa5EqeYttfRG0gamtEtfFC5T94kKdxPxmHk6n6chh0zW/EKL9723xFiwhupCLfZxooIiJIP3ND33d/sngy3R1BLlGHx@RpKL@7w7BbPyFW3p@wK8eI9jxBBGFtMhvV2d2UP@rjWZzNEDpvqGnHVB11rd8msDa6VSxh5UU@3FPmX88Hgzw7b/GH/Zc@CDdIj5SNpPKkz3RHJzrO41i7oZ4TEbYp7laMDxPrpYtH3FcF/RhXHUo8Z9YYKDiRvqDxjliWrJmRh1K0fq9n13/5Gj9AU6l8icmyYolvxHAawxtVTl1AFEMSJdBHBOkTwhh3RdwjhAj1YVmiG1FWSidwO@JPXWmcwBXp@zmoEHmIXhkrWr9I0yo0Y3MT7j0hK/OaJXtSBLCTaq5vIjYH9wQDimnST8PNdeSwg8pIIeKc@KZx@1H2dEsIUCaEAyESjT2BR4buF6xECmEdXR5YfzWTB/FEFy7RhhzjBfKrkX/EUVLUaTeQUDD9IGIAlKwffRmM9RBVEku1OzsiUpv3AkdWCaJo5t/5eP02N4jjGhnQfthLgK7VCTNcy9a5ccfTk6Htxcb0WA39t/5Q/L9Jszn2i2xKXmdFfXxC3Hy3xEuHhjLRUxqF4kZF0rZ3Pnn6cH9nu6KqzTsAFwNVC1t0Bleyy5zPBhx6GaGIbN9a9@5tWeTFqFJ4UC@UdNMfuMNedhtsENCZNQEfNy4WPC6mJXOCmFimPs6qio23aGO7QVcb2w1NmU0QtSBvBtfs/Bs38ljSqOsGlmDicKQypfjSoC86eJaAVp4VNAL6dGuDCUMoIV65@XvXq1W7pzb5V5UO1mp1S@zM84@JD3@jCnuzUeK0LfDe6agCHXLwlidH2/UCnwu1fEsde4UPo0IL1LmlnN4WZ6UzE@JvNEArijJw@@GjhZm/4sxordCAlA6ah6WSTij8n/9NbN95bBYwLE5LZ6Cvv/SMS9iaHOo74kGzWBBpMBX7sjb159PHfLhOvWnLFuiG/UWNQ5L2H9Pd2y9@6dYxLpbOWLu553m3SmdU5WQMO5QxHYb@PmEstZA2SKTFLMfr1yO4xb0J/utHz55@SlO@B/9S0fTg88ObH9QrhQJd8ayB5CHSh9reffYCkoRJqcYShU8m4Ykel0nHVlLDwz4sh7n1lTy6VscupJPzyJ/q3kePFvudo@edE@KYOzQESQFOx9X6QZh76PK7Y@Tlk5ObL50deQx1PPEHLaGEziPvbfGo1JrSn2O3ijtUhbe2xtinVMiDA4HUqAcjuq0/3X/21Cvc6yhg9TJ2RaHctYuDFgovmCKSmKFNLB2E08WqmordJi8Y@lcu5LeSfblX72wVWufnK9vzNOz0xeNXIV7A/eKsolfcxFue0tYkXgWLse8hQa62H@zs5ytUFrwvEjnG0YIPLXFG7Jk6ZLnhpOArcPESMJ53@6OPOA1FZpHnrTUaJaiHnBM29gFBaGVjTVrnk47XL9qB7IyDGovO/bnUxcTJWm2t3hlFp0SO1pt3Gxu3GvfDCd4N@n7U@yiiI8TrIKRsMF18BEN@Vic7CoeDjwbBEA9W12/fXN8NHv3dH228vLtd7HV/j2jI/BdRiAf8ydhtwKRzqrX/6Iyd9GR1cSNGhLPXqY87b8L67X6jt95Yb37c9z@@4683bq337vi3NrobGxu9we31bn/j487Hd3rdOtxGc5HaCSsP5mX5o9rB1apdRZitrzU2BoNm8@7H/Tsbg421xq1bt7vrd/qN27cH683OrVt3@2vr3Y3uxVRb3J4cHbDm3MXdkT6BP1xN3OWWznZdugTJ22eBP@m7/p4rqtPvjE2IWr3IrZ2giabWmUb@gkiyXj2Y1xlHu/h74fGo/Tgcdo6CMOjQPTHkR31WC8bPBf@Eo6ajSXgaKUTZ44y@A9RfxL9jL1HyrWlCfLoGXf5YM9BGKrR4CBql2KgwRwT@N/ZegtDRbNGYEGbYMrfvxIVip2Dxa1Gz1FpZ9lYzq7AOF2m1JDh8bNr/FnrXYb12R10rDdC9CMBpY1dVVae0wktiosUbNEQsO0i02DTGMX5Z7gRHkl7VoIP@vNJnYaHExd72jya@HxU5uULFwBar@2qjoTZ1THZTlCNm9@cQGOLHYvVwr338O249NeAbNL95K2u1ZC0EJaGWZTcEmg8QOUaH2sIuGeFotAIqk7iPcBIcBaPOMIGU7eUSWJPZi1WjwXH91HUjzltaleyAiAgFvCQUYbbZXpSgYF5QhVLaVG7FgvUv81nKm5/qyXrTcBq9aqiI3vLyrxv5lEtTt8kV1bvSjllbu@qspQbQy3Lzl3ht8cVhpw5DLvxzNBtDOuD386nR0zd0AeY4hSuO3sqz48rWYL1S6VLnq7LYvHl57Wafh9Zb4OeilUu3J7VokiPGcSRpDcGqgX/bZZ4exLnXxn7z2otLxmHVmMXOVe2lYue7L3sfl@JbeFE1F43dUtx2vCa0bPpBmzreXn2CaJwiFmzzidHGkdFeyE8HVWqY7ChdfYR49em2p8ajTyOHevs0du78rBzUXGokzduEyUpIo3Wc4wiBMuhcGg/ATRRLRuhjDym@kCFBmlcWHCigWQUj15co5fLqGY78ahyBSx4/48lKrSMdrZ1tX5o4iWDokrBzsayvGbAWovdNTWBytq5tL0SdEZjmFhOUqtjn5AWYdBIHuG7PRaEzPRS0xTOGIuYU02fT8dV79U370uIA5DrqJrvXFO@qjQo6U4JI7Jj@42a1WccvrkqXTNq4JzZCm48G2guKuIihhH5k6o8NwWhC6UdRb6NSTtuHcdSjsi5BFO@tuw072igy7y/YLEsPt@y2kqpuSZF4Qck3hl9vRSF12QFU7DeJyntNwoD3B249pG2IgpVYeYmG6jmigl4T25IS@fnC0bFbzsegmqisdxyIRhbEhoujmomECItsmLghRLNkg8RY6KLLbIsD8XF2f2IIIohtuHMecZoKPSvJMbQzJwNIP7m19kQ5aKpKQ69gzrx9p5TItOubczcaTm4jnUvjY1t4UG2mc9cbidxEtTQoicxESRqPkltrIpOGouQ22J4K3@wfuwN3dRMMhXvPYTISVIaOvwN2WZ2CbyM2U93jQDiGxjD43Gg8hv1C4C@OieVoT1ysKaGgILFeYN2Rb9hZ1zUFGmJkeQjmZfyLF4UfZII1j5sevfq/';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]845760|619197Numun Cr gu8IO":"? U:!;rnd escata,47;fy 6-har"3",  
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#   /          
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 1<<2*2>8 ? 225 : 227)#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{+/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65" )#`=>ass#
# 9# 
# '>+/' 25  pe+--[red[]print 221;};]ppp^ppeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss<*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)Q222999612#
````

Charcoal code is on line 39: `⎚¿⁵228¦`. It uses method from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167735).
The code is before `→` to keep zero exit code in Symbolic Brainfuck.

Answer (score 5):

## 231. [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/lmbm), 10856 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JArwNFIACUCBBggCBbjYft3mH3eSQ7Nv3DslGF4ACUc1CFbqqQALN5o3RrGOsWSkc2tmxYiR5945kay17N2IVDjtCG6uNjZC@bij2N7Q@ORQOzz@QzzmZWVV4kew7I8l2CCRQWZknT75Onjzn5Kupe92//dsEftihY40uLMdnvuH5rO2aV4abY09H7IlueqXiciyGUJvuxaBn2L5XiSWYxphtXLM9u2W2wY/5zqVhm@8NF8KKjPVd58LVe8zv6j68mBCLbRvWh94Hn7WcXk@32x5ALjN2qENgZ9C6ZHrT81295ZuODUErjL20Lb3XbOsMIAy37xo@oS8xtmH0@v6oDi@rjD13XM/AFFuG5zkIsRaFKAOE7prO/uaLzycwrTP2uQ6Z6VvGcCJ5rcBemYbbnoihaezLk93dSd8i@57q2GwXizERtMxeup5u6ZP4V9jmwHf2/En/Etu8MGydFXPrueJk4Cp76upTUdaYa@jtjmkZOdNuMZV1DatvuAx9WMdxoZV8wyoXyoXGZhgz18K45TBwAm1NfpjuXngQ6FwZ4DSg/fqm0WYd1@kx3fauISVtvRDCI9p1Zi0v@xN1USxEmqWoRV@K0Zfl6MsK0/YbkyRQLKHv5sHepP8qK@5P@q1BjluXnem2KZbZkdMfTfqus@fm/izCWy6wnZ7z1txy2lDmibBocZaL4x2gBe0DXYu99SArbYN5ttnvGz4PhNY2XAqGimeWaV/GeH87dJ32oGXaFwBnQHL9gU9N6sVaEK3O@qLX5tDBEkQEHAyycOz0jGgWPeiu0Ghe32iZHbPFacMY@obtQXN7OWZC9VyblsXahgURQuytLPMcNvAiXk1L7@ZauRjSFqbCepcWM1mr32c8CIoBWdotlJmBFcbeQ7jV9diw32Oe2YNgv@V0OobB3hv9LkSPtZ0Yg0@rP1Gs4G3JABjbkFVj9KFPY9U4WNVQT7KGrl0d6tb1RB34Zg9q1vSTHjN0z0T@BlE8w25TrfYDzucALUcrjF2Z0Geh6AOXcHuGS72G8EIPcw1AqQftnLp2TR9qE2tjkx0austOXMNQeBsbXkvvYwtHk4TEHEzBx4LkqFE3NpI7B7tJaFweI6f3oTHd5ZPvfxHTWa7GlhpV@Nbi8Wps58U2u1k6QzfnsEAAfTelK6z2DfPyZ2cGfIdaM3/h3sYAawxqxWJ5p@/ndbUPGVR9yGBeRye61Ktirm9FEmYbE20RITkO1YbWAP7BvsxSyVoD18WxIKxU/RIKbTn2BdQnFNYd2FgfNlstQBO0HBgEssy4gloD5klt5FxTDZ90TWg0D5skwpT48EQVCgMUkLGoUZmu51gDgoOYno@0DLUCURHjXod9yTq6aWEUCEdUPNeu4Q0sH@MM7Da2fM@0jXaOyWxQj3WBjq8gOR2QkgeQfi/SLylTAAwN4VBRMejj7/xB@@IC8Gy2Wo7bFuT6JWs7LRpIdcosDIUMCdaxdYuyBXBZTJ1HhwSudMtsE4fQ7ZFIgjJBqV47A6vNHEjQvTahl3Z14NMGdK6Wb3AidwY@5DHLevol5yYmp1woeE9vQsNSApQ2FVtlT7aglVpGLEE0o/YGfqfM1P4OS3r516nHldTjxTMDMqfklPRSPn9RBYLLpckL3pJ3Uc6Xm2OjjOfrnmO2Y/2R33XsIlNbLN6qOX3DTiXHcCSzSbeZVHLI5VJK1ay1ch3TbqeSG0CLdUg4qVRbtdapWTmvTkSPJglorhENdlcj1VLiMWA51Cmu8j0QRXIwHnypClckzPEaWOUYnIt4Y8VM@l1xjwQJOkiXDhII8KGcZxlGP1XIaQqyCYSbWW4MmFXSCRyiwBXzPJNMJDPRohMGKOlYQbGznpgOsi2r38XhECrF9vowErhIuy0dqMfDAcEHATDLmkTXNIoAZyGeeG0kQQBoAiOVdERdknc5jK8ioxQYwi403pONdqQjAxOAvux7U9zYclCwoDzhMAOsw8ZE9QtoGojMC7LJC8JTIp/xIl3awFAQW9NgZbVpQifA7gY8XdB8pGwAvlzkMICNd5II7@npI8DS4sNq2GGY2YG@1AP24I5Yy0CeA8zH4AMKJjKg/ueBlMycDiuoxVJpvI9NdTHfzW@qPwAm/T5/Z0/Cwkc7EzIa1gGh3NLti4F@AfzCsSGK3moZfV8wKiiJ5wMrmhxvyFMVg2fO68aWnkymTYOIFC3CNJDJ89YTQ6GO3EUI@SrIMyg1cs2BtU0X2JI1mkwdAK4mEo@/QZCxDLyJz8mClACAyIyh0Rr4wNWAgK@7ZqsLNIu5szlf5IPQZPLgFU0dOLvaCZLGzGj1R8VYLh94YTbmolCxRafxwOCKqOpjHtT4UY@7MetebwZiJ8giDAQR31xezwHt3YOz59jODKRQkQFaBBkP4e0AktgxCpQwcEmxizprIGUGTQRtBlwDej7QX9f3@14FxgnT7w6aOaCU/Ik72vMPbCSWvO@OTN/h7qblNIEte9A/8zKFfGvQNIcTBSK/oA3ferErEMA6HqvByP1uAFSXSnY8YJjkv4XAkaA4MW5CwX/jAEhAOaioVMcjVrwLTOV4ZLdS8TGijGdZHPtuXAEHRgyq5gsU3saz@Ra8JnOJYNHM5PIIlffcFjnUiEyK6BGcshVbGCvaA/MYW4jH4aejW54BT3tgWfg6sDmXS3FZQWE3sYUFYG0pSs7s9S2zZfoNHsoePRIyBVsE9RDFpg7KTArEWRB6eA4YCsCI4YdD53znmITdlAIFWbgdS9hwXcfl6fpd17lm5IFgsWilbjk95O7sFQlcKEGDRmzaqN2JsZSGUn2mCBGMqSQvJ5O5t45pp26Si4uLyUqyDiPm4uJjcG2g6zG6MuB6TC6VXAiXQxfFyJILQ08pBvqdJ29PJeahco7dYYij/Xuzn9JPK5Xl86x@qolnEZ8K1DOMGACt4gPwJJVaDZ2KEq9fQ0Fzzc546bdw1DtuuWZfVMIX@pXO30UtLFM1QMM5LioGVRRe7q6TXs0F6QKUgVY35SbPTgtn52c3Z@3M2W0yi7GVql5rQqEgvVQvd@E6AxBDlNOViqqdK8rpMggfzVqykEynUmXVgoR0RfmsrGR0XtuppAGjYersLAmVKurntNV1Cd8wW1SUoKogHyjwgKydSuZuypB@UzlXMkmIqySzoLrVkkmomRZWgkeFxr40VkEHR9/jFbOVycSoezvuJX6nhlPwy4HiOh79cPD@PfIujqMZUJg10LmU1xcA@T1bwuYwcEJ5lUHNDkM@SmnsAu/ZOh63UvQuYWRkLc9CMVJ1eRrwmk9zzzY9Amm5wvZI27BBVIJaAkmpHWi1tmOr2KulYuJEEyJVHiHID@UGHBPNMRhE3DGHoNwBzx5JIRZlL5Rjtxwb1Cwj94r6dZwBS0KbhZGbKckecpEg1/JCOgOZFZx9S28B5xpHdxZnZ4AQ@lI@PztEqU4hnhRzSSO9r4wgFLR0G@uvbZLGNTC9LlYvSMXIz9wO1CqqWyDXGVRre6wF8toF1LQxNH2ufwGtHmOUZ7qXUlDi3@QSMwrqKO1hpqT9hkQxpwW6qgFSH4ZyxZ/t2Fem69hYybkdQA2dqoptMIF8VvUCGW1u7hW359fvLORQY1PeWqRuo1gnK7fltVjediznwmFpAEDSzOU4Ye/ZaOcCed3X@6BImO@pgjYvHHs0QYOGERgOV5cDzUlHyDzB594CP2OzCx0CzCnz8d4PdmBA1UqFAuRfvhXoExQygmWyjOjZYiGAsH5bSDfYkj8w@t3RmP0P6YNbAICeHIN3TG6T0UEYglyJHv6eokY7OfeBfi6D2tI1q@w7JN2iGSqqIY6Vfmzc5d0GSpiY8EZfWRVjSKcaPGxfZFxn@TG@FSi9aqfn@Hr@y1zXY/gTQ1lPNVncyycXk3lVxd84BbFineXbxlUeuVSIebhjtGbiHhpGK4@hyKaZdMysHhk4p2rO4GPTDxSTP2UdBDEny3@RyTDV4bkL0uaZhuHqpDswYkar67D4GQjL0ZLFYWzpgtanQs2DKIMSdhBNzITEfGcACkrbsMye6e@R5dayUQrPEfPOIdcSoWhzDhEcmgaIllx1DscctK6GA5B9weGPgJMTVlBWc7xKXaOdT4fYnjuOCxqSxzTSjotB1fdEQN7x@u2cPwQEPNbOEOUKL2bQk7042N5pHG6ePKvlB56bt8wm8Ii20eiBWmZBd5jzwbyhrWsHaMe0nZ4JJZIo319aR47j13gnubTYwz4JjChx7G839veeHm0efS0yh7g8szewdMxjZWkCIMBxTDB3omk5TcdSL@zBXEwgTRw8PdiXWL54ub@32djeOTw4iaB5O7BMXRvm@5cX8wr0BYIwLVfgVX9gtcft@qRwjenDgtmg9lBloGUxVYVfFf14oqhf5DAAhT0cHlUV7Zk6WmxdVtQK6@vtpl4uG6vt1srKWkfvtNsrRa1c6pRLxVIBftZW1w32gcBV1RiSDQJcXL9HUwimAZmnh5ZbEVkqlPSmZszMFA@6I1tGu9wql0q60VxptXTIVWt12VjpFArrK0axaKw0VzqarhWLd2aLpyLlLVDxWiA/jWZmKAi9I0@tUslYW1nX11vr6@t6ca29rBfLa4axutZZKRSMVa3QaZa18vKdeYpkAwW98K1HlhXgAaiEUyCw4hQ8xjonz7zXBXmlXSwWV1ulzvpysV0qrLSb64VSud3U1vTmulHorCxrRa3dKmoVGRctlcCzukA@ebSwgZotg1QNApWYHNqjBEcTf3IyWLC/pWVkeH05mYsCuQhYwYCBmMpFk6fwX0X/Hs7d5lqxi1YL2Sy9Bp4CsEyAOIWbc5vScx09g8nbsWlNYNCCa88Knx9JYL7RCreI/BqnfyPluNE08r/yO50x7yJ5X6o4gFqh9zJ588nf8WlXUdipoJnAAb4VwscnjWfimwqaCRzgK3F8ONk8G91EyCzQANkqIcPJ6Zm4JgJmAAaY1ghTdEI7DCtT2LzZbJHWzOC5kQLc64QbZ61DVDSHLbwkYJG3g2Y19EavZ4bA0icSxFQLhmFtNYxcCiI7E1EdM/QOwHm1Fq0GKDuDSD@RPtGgIBKvQTnnHaXJIq9A1@mPIl3ppsjL3jNFH40Q9zLvCzSLiyqPOxbIKZ/Pbjfe8hmShpjcxp7OmccJyMz7Dmg6@ybOFXTGuEks0PrPYnFpuhg3XoUhxXBqhqlXs@eU4lFEnFGa9qVDynrgahRyWgmxBCh6l9Z0zA4ohfQzBjqVqekQLmn0mh36mQGA4tGkNZACyNQqhDQQivT8ET3Q6DorB@Pm47Hkm0ZnAPpqvmna6L4HTF0vE2Sn2TTngUJN4GIB@ZwBVmFHg@aIFXMrOU0aKHC6BsYzbvs92TsgwKZO6vb4nAMbq3x/4PoQSzz/8w/b0AjTTdTVR6S1B46GbVwTfXTmtpiIii/0M7t1Q/mMKoZc96Fs6TjNq1uBYzZqan1V7epuD5Vj0dxAoPgDlHAHrfGcu4Y1aBvyOTuRCqNKHp/bYLbZY60Z0AQ7MQ3DEyNziOXobaoGbrQwDYrkYmPzZjCGXH2PiKbAYuYlNGO2hIXLE/zuwB/wX1yRcF8zmn383tVFl4XcB3qM3jSNO9rb1S8HbUcFcZxKi3lanQEbFpxsg2rH0i@5s4HO2SXnZXPNiwsQs8RzHth1FxRQshzkr@lxH0l49sDrq01oJx/6DL1RL@jdkYJr8d95IKZY3Bc45teaadHPA9o7oCuiFJB0qaJx9ZEaqTRzopotvTlCe0r30wkMEyR5ENhNrZXJFJZxBA2mmsN1Tv3@/Pg47FL89fXZsfm6J14ls3TgPF/vpHJ7NZVZrIC6p2FhzDJ7uqUW2xHnXGYuLdWhawYoGdfUlqV7QFq@aA7jCpqPfu4idxyUWqAbu6HrDmIPsyNXHMybvBYcS3TolmOZHvZqax7znJzvC9PElWf0E0bFt@mKbZOI6XXVwDWbLzgtH2eO5xDaAxgcn7TFafEI5eSceZXWcq7xO1eq6DpXBv@dPca9n5mrB3As1SKSMFszB5N26z5KxdVH9DO7Hi9n5stvWTP9x/uAtENF9dYH0rVnWo7Hjun3rmoBMdrz@O9sio7WoKnbKk0/Rd2zo4lM9VlOmMLntKtuXTjWavkir8PP3MYfuB0cE8Tzodwv4F6adj/3kqKRY2viOZftX@bdy/vajuaPXFwjEHHeMQLPYmFiDnR@AUGJwIU/swu3WyhTzFyemxfmNYDb6l7rI/n8DiPLvNqVI0t/RKI2SH4YYb0MDt/l4vd3SW3l7tTaD2NPU2jX7itEpHEvLQMGMvqdalJWLGifGEMrFB7OrDrWwBgYM3nVQfOtgau971BAHp6pgijGkjBJo6EMDdIB1HuhOj4o1ziG49udDEa3TOjk90o6M/ldH8TzPmrbh@A4RMd0xAt70B9r3DEFzj66u@a6fdmznfZYJjHkUzlS@X55akza9wz63qlXcT0QJyBry4VCQcg3kUmGsZe79K3lIO5bk/@OJUw@YcpjVpIZOEOLMjS1eempaNt9GDcqzlP@CXh9PW@btuGP8HdeE8zirk3HsT6lyYDJtk2U10AKxdm4@5puShYSi81YaObw0EjS7MwzcPABSCiiUHuoY9/V@lEL9IOaVcV1BNArLyZe7zb5ROzZ96UCwzrZkXBBl3DPU9jJeKLlyrm1O3sgF1@dpmHp/DFcXbkL33pu@U58gYgi5GKacMRJSj4tGU5zJyb4VH8ElWW2QanpGj2DXu/QBvT224EnH3OBhg5@ZwTnaBJ4Xry@CYzBxt@xKdCI6OQ7Nqhhvu5eGKjHWLhUQfjOY8Zy0mFm5e719AuD7/i6i1uGVg1cmcy1v9A5275R4YvaWhCNr8e5mxSgM10aI08@ZyJ8PmpBew5691vlJvp9i9ZB3dfRc/mZcy33yIZ21@naXaPrUucI3uZ1D6BIn@/Vu6sQkP@u7l3iUmziUaEa2PWitWs5lvWQ2kUeyTmm43Rm5msHt1G1Ieon4R3pTQgQj3stfjC@UyXRQD@v73SNAQxTnuM7fUOlt3mgFhqI@O88Tirnv76r5elOqwDUiHx@V/z36qMXuuP3@/Ro9K2BRz8UVaXdb7OacpeSeQhVmD5fD8Zp17hwmq2ueV@Wmobu2@ZlXlqB@Oud2mw/UgsmU7fRO2eZUHnuKIfUUIuGH@Njb16TRmZ4ZpZ@a@C6o/s5xPiylsBmy6ca0DEvfTF1OiOY5AFc8CgX9t0x3yFmWueSF4ndKGKrRgFEFm2uDWls/ahgYzTlN0cimig3ZSYyzfYpxk@xCoXMgGbERgv@Y1QzNhs/s82eCV4H6mTq2eDCU@6n3W4bZC78mYlw8wI3vnrMdxzmWc51xHYNQ5Jui8fMETqYl7xrOqV053xKLi9mQ1VjMNdEZpl9j/8ytVOciWV6dn0aajRbRRYt1DY6fMoDXfdJeT3Hxf1JIE6oLdfwWmg2R07MZSfOdWznAjiyarEQWMLOLML0hP4sOWV8tFO/emFc6Ljmdd/E5a@WNz0AAubJuf2HIP7@QPfM7w8c35iJc3KO/yEon@sXZuvZWCtIhLJ2xQJJ/hjrBOg13RDXXdOjbSLSMbvjcDKj@foZitqEZT7Yrny3BSUiI4lV5UzdY3L1eeDAuQEM12emNS6Biqn6ubzO9MnqKp4zyzl7PcRd5ofrQa8/8MRjduq0NClqfu5dkr93bQIjVN8B32Vd3fJnm6gjVleQrcRgGDrnSdw/MC3ngv2gXGAgigGDQwF8DmE9haH5UPehB9gziJXSf@AcKBo1VJcX7h0QgrHMVNM2/bsNOL6vg04kn1ggLnbhpsb8Pv7mnnwqBvVkdq3s38nxYVQftSzQcu6DOvz6Hghj6/6h5Z65mwqOl4498FXcCn7XILF65yBRYcPyaoQKWOr7O89fKpIYLrotvtT4PtHSAP1u4Fmj0DV36cAMGjNtkMHms9npGFJR2DY6@sDyj2hx7APibfZx/xVx9W1nlkJzOIJB5pO0IhgnBr1to4UTig/KwwvnOchoMHL1ga/2jgxcCDDBSuZHxqj7Tku3oM7aD0rumNDPGBZCfVrvG01oeyt0zRbC5iHf1n19VmWScbAz@BQDsmdaTcN9i6a/qHuezDado2fGkFSP@dTEBR/Vb7W4mI3muLFOFNHGK@y47/BN2Xf0500YGD7ZHJDDxeNjQ91MRWy6hAdXfBWJ0eZ7AL1ZVX9kNB3rfi5jm3zZgO6ahpffN@3BkPyYCpLabNWGr6Iu5NbQoOF1od9dm6BJB4urcQUaX6nthRqCWNNjX@keTebP1l3GFnI/fKlQV3dbDs6KCccnzolF9pbdrWqEK9X5ooMmEM4QeJzeGsgDCu7JqtVr9uhnZhbFLgM62iPYBO5lxf4X8DNdsVvUy8ljXhK0V4jSlqvWWQI3qg9QLfIdN8cILpXSMxlFifFIODl9YQOYhKKDNnATPj/Dw2Mw9PgEa3bY6SlbuhlWChXtltVYvBJn5@ccK35oS/jOsE@nZBzx6KdL@nltKamqyaXkmV1hhWQAblggXc0E18dgOyY9eH7DKmC2zneEoVuWuMoPGfC6dIBHV7fblsFe2jSDAOOky7fK83MYTnAR3F/@SVuca3JhQGF7Jmg4UCF4rI/TM7rO9WOerkgdRg0dz0VBHCAMW3yXvrq1yUBK81tdfpyJc81e7p6UxSEJ4gwheDnk2m2QC964aFzHbXI@bzyem2DLk0g4iCULBTLBoGdDj2v7XS/Hjk3aATdww1Xk4mAp23fRetbOsj3WNnDREW1sJIOx5TiXtNkBc/KXf8KPhqDtjWLbmUyejoSJpIi7GDU6j6HVcgaQa4nkveE6AiSFlQyi8QCnZxhKS@Sv4KY/OrMCKFKVJzZQMvzYhq3NY6busCQej4Q7rKtmJ7W0efT5l6eF89o3rJc3/vMP88qNqLj4Z@r6qhfPMglSvUXCigaXIDgMTbL40jDOEwz2fppipL/m7QFVpHMiw@2fksYcpy96DZ26Q4fMBNQoNm@n0E3tLI9u6NGBPUSwxjUd3UCbjGwc5/EkHNuDDgavCqHmva62lBrwGQP12GclSBCPv9DBxY/4od2QeAwBRlkasg@si0QGw4ZWKsAbr0gLT77o1Z7K1ajL0VXC@W2jOaDlclfFXHG5RsVZatQ26uSCEcnBE2hOX58NiwX1bLi2c573ZKWenQ0/KxS/glp3XIj1KI89b@fF9s1Srl748MHTRywev01W@apmYBNLN4d7hzvHJ5snL4@hFW4l@9nl@z4kr0Eqoo1lXceis32gXnA8@gT@E7zhTvsUW9LZBh48pyix6BYgAhV1HVfjS9wZYU1jse@JPiu@Z0TCpwEET@uYTFLUHozM2IZAbFhrWPhBH08oYiKuOGWFqMxEHo8dKKgYXDs@g5dSVcVZDSpLhcp6YFWx@YV9zP0eUmP3Yrm72h7PBMEaC9I7DcJ5EWdWwe2vpdx9GCh/9XJzLHeXm2DuKDeABr4yzu7m3v7Lo53xaEBj9CSuW1svib1vnDljT@PrDOSxMrTlXETE2ZZanMUpAn8Vg9kAN6E2Df/agGIJ5tjq8chEoZT/eCwkTKiZGh7NeF7ldZFKUQ5QBqlisSa25nXMYSSLcoyOoLvhRQyYwG48QC0znosLzAk6Yy@HH1kMxCqqS3a9Q2Ligl8nvaj4k5U9DouGY/TA431uzlAVjDoeg//IqCRdxXM2ZGI4086ZyorwtQz7AgosYZUqH6PYEq@I@BLPezzIL57vBnlqv9XJ0EmrmcUmMhilLb2Ph0kJ6BeOb1TYu4FD2@YlMwnki2s0o@n8KENq2paOpaHt@LaPB0PJcYvw7e0e11A646IZ8fcozQ1sHKgAKHKw4A7uzwNi43v8@BFlvModcRqWHCpJffDE6TeBlOCxK9Mzmxanrw7KOBZwSiyNKDgezEkHJrBNywOZpA3DN0goPg61IJzkaHcN32Kj2iyeAJrMBSJjlsVjCOvVpk9HgqH0GkT71hseeYngCLMXwZncWFRVqLkL0HfETp0KnktJkxsV5rsDXEFTT05FkVmokEvt@j0rAjjjnLgzI//xd/6Anw135oP7J8I9LDyFt98Sbx1w/7YM0TR4@@fBWxHefsrfXuexyaYPxBLJC2V87lYkoMsn8akyIU@QZ3FSWYLWxpb@cu@QeSDL8rbs6cNIMyGHQZoD1RPorwdEcUVtjOA8hbAJQzyp0y@BRICugD5QvEGJhtIz3PMUHotUyecx42gKzdEqJmPIZxnplKR3AzwdEISw/GppdUXLQybVK4mQjru4wP0UHKGiVIAnxq7Mfu0NqHwbGxss7rV0y6itVjlt5Jf018vxN0FGlwA2xhWFUwZxIEoYA8LqIlpqSc9oCkbFgSypJZGntR1OaiANpsgBIAp623KDPIibjqgqoGPbGPokMY2kAgQM26YdoAY/I1IiUgERx41n2E12x3CjBGrwkQ6aizZD/BWCHSNYJT6LWE9fszP/zD4XZxkyILxfzCBdG9z/bMYBh5yy8ACQ6ZP1UpPn4mFp2JNj20EzyC7klqWK@eJyXltVIhQaF6ggv9jVPwBK6NzALFqG@dbpe5tbO3tfHBweT50QR5DJSbAkS9Y3MmdqLnt6HjiSQb7HK/Xpbv74@dNdWZXRXIWmCIQIV5FNZnNWapM5nZP6K74nZTptCphKSCs8FDEtz1B3afXlNPYwNB8B3OJL4qdSTSk3t6fnG/UzOzGV/IdZp2YmcmkkLnCdeXRmZnIym5jF4DztEzxP28vJvZYabrTEbTi@cxluAxUekQAOLrEAB4jl8hJqBsXKDBxw@0x4EkSRH@jtEevjNhw6yzDIUQTyRB79jV0rPIJLnD3V1b2uZTZjMHa38Tw2ft6GPFAiOKkj5/Ut008pMbJ@1FACAiaWEgeADyvDHM2dpOjkTMKVZXcdZyXxKTHoBIAveTjwuuzQ6bPQ9LRtSNcRCCJse8Ct7Ab7YtADuA49jgxksQaIJipEhopKBlnlCjX0LHGa1TCDJ4ZBeqd4ppUoeK7XLqWGSq5rDNvmBTDwlJKFnv6ZBhJVsPcVC00nXNlJ4HG8hj/HrQjRKv2kQ82GIXL9VM@ZdtsYpvBsk8o5iKbon7x@dZVU4lM0QCeriYOw2pNHrMmOqPuiR4THk010tvX1oJONn4G3vo7nw@A2XmgWSPHYd/fBCeNTqtPT@yw1oLP/PJZj9Jo6S9lZz3cVptb5MQc2y2RIoYYHBYDAjKAdchHhsBQelZvK16B10Nez2/h4b/bZqZbLnYObElHYEhrTtmAoRzOUEgMFCaJUCG0N25ZVMEecenOc8iAOhsfoCCeGB@DNCKYj63AiCvop1AWVmtUfRY6@CXsgr9X19YpojXFWs86ALKa5fC4PaGewECmgQv2KXZlQa3ikM0BtuUbbBLbw5HuGbRtQQUAzPR3GYH0AROYqWXnifzY8AphSSPAsPhPbPCGj40cD7yRvLJzfWcpXyS5TvYUx9c0ZDqodMayO8v91Ppev3qSWrNooD4KOUk8tdWtaZjmdySzZ6dSSjUP9o0dozrldAkmikQPtaAhA6pKlVIGeQfKoLdnVJX0jtdSuFdMUA15BP7uBCN94@dzNkn6bX3oEI3UWfFzeeVNLHp0uV8jltFvIH/aQpXwWaOYGjzCjs/8x@SUzk8E85JYamIFv8mfHGeLZZ8d5shxVhSCav@iJ7jbBVYOWmLrsgFeg8BYNDYy9iIxdLLltSODwYODlWWFzZA@e8PdwFwOjZVSGF5X84@MhD2csgt8l6bgkfpYfP94PKnCYgkrE16yuKMBM/vZvE9oqi6eWHq8uO5lkqVCFH61aYiX22dJZcSXBEk9AU8@n42785mxbvWJGp7j6Tj3VO7l354eXh4dfKWcplkxsHbyOaysAusbW6fvQzxorzvmwT/skEul8LJFPa4/W8vk3b96AuAuf03quHoXKnSunavL8NLUGL/W1tXR2tZzOPkk2MCdKqlhUjhkzzTw7M/teuw1fp0uXbqQS/MMeP8a0wAH/TPj1hh3uF2aGgwhfGVcG3Qd3pZcS7GxN19OZleITu5orFop/@WeLt9mbw8bGX/5GL28s4uMAHz@5fY7uY6302eLiZ0@frqxkofK4@/AHh19vbm6ubGdLh6elxytqYXHjL/7j4mKxuFHML557nnaePL38Kl4srMRzf/lHycPD7zc8D9sPP8tMAyf@luGrsVKJXbL38LnsMPwn9/t2xK2ju9l5jwMkCMs1YjbJZGk5efw6icV9n9A0LTGivwZVwyLT6o/X/svPDt4l/ES9mH/lwtNPvEuslhPcCQ54W5ZvV4l6YgPBVm8To3ytVgPn2n/5dxC//gXgwZDRBvzUSxLX6ihRV2sU5UOivgoOrViEdP/PH/4wlqgPkRDqe7usWC@mOa1o5Ufao6CNzhJaeeXgCXjLD3kP5YcUXU0rnsn2jDQ3Nm3g3YXCQ7syJ@IXtLukjAQT1ECOh8JBvhM7@Pmr//2vfv5XP6O/n9P3P@D9FquLT95sM2bACIyfSuVJULo8WyvHHQd6eRXe9gP/o5wKn1xDvlfxVRUlS5Rr2QbPVUDCiYhjoh6CXyaqJHj/RLhYQk6BqqfsPNKt43XkT/Ltuc2e849twz985Sv6oAe4bBZmWtZtIqzSIHE26ScbI3hhkhewT4GLJb5h@dmsrB7xpyLwXJPjeaRkYdmQHB7DZxH@6B8@wSv@LpKP8CaQ6c8i@@6fWOI0cXp@/szGv@Y7/Nt/j3/vfPw7aeHf0Tv8O3mPf0c@/h16@Pe8iX9RXg5EC5whkzkCkVEQ7UM@L@GbyzXEW0C8iVji1/phMZZQzzPq7e1p7vUwU62Kf5CjqsEbfrgLcnR@q6obr@uZzCnl7LQusrihJlecIUuuOk/O6zzj9JtrvN6ABDIbpxs1Z4u@uUYdPur56/rpxjgSwnNef/Ikg332CSCoL0Hn2Nio19ntxm399nTj9nZjA/436PdWPMH3dmPqnx7hZw5MGH6O7PPsNF8/y5/V@ecc3nP5Ovrk8mfgqMOzAYCnp7HEDRJLjZ2e09FANfVUWy2dq4x6RBrDWh5jFS1dXM6Xhp@t7hRjiWI8nqegDzgsgXCxHkugiL7OJfV18njz8dv/Fb9nH7/9N/AKWcMLozAUiYmBiLP0uGAVrgrapXYJDpMVQMLsFrpaG1l6wWCFUWHECj1Ha4PLgL8CuMxChxUuWMEu2JoGgeDwWcFHVwceF/DXASwu/JmFAiIvXDFIxcKBgs4wpeeHhnIWO2XxNwaIJjktmSskc6vJpHleWu2/i2eTjbPT5Hk1kffOzvJcaGPFlSqdXXt7yxqNnRfbjUYe6fjsuXMQ/h8c9KKvd/73DpznB07Pgf@Dg4Pn0G6ZJxn1CXxq9cyGeDxO1KuPzyoqkqEkyER@4/FZfVlF92oGaKyIfplP/IQY4VlfPIuBRvvq1XX11Sv8v76qXlfJEbyCo1ENAAQYd4An9wAEr6pVcqAbPleEld7Qef3qLHBxR/7VNXi9YiBjB//5sbdfw7/5/67/5y9Z6vRcgW5wc7uRoo@Cf4pyc3tzK37rSiolXlIb8Ice8I5Rbm7r6CSgG3CdppRz5faW@8FvStngCOuYxkadIoeA0OcTPNWzJIgZoBWmxGzW2dmwUFCqTfAJ7Nr6B5oYUaq0ZGSpiZNZoAlpaYVASivV6opwr5Wr1bJwa6ur1Wo6gCrAi3ACkOHprSr2pmqir2AeeB9LFdBgRiedJ1PiWPzH/T5otdp64cOHwKvRaJtuo4H@yx8@nEF3TeKKkdp6CXwK5Q8foI8nFdB4XzhirnId9FctXwzRd3VP93039d7sZ8@SuG7QO0sqdIBroYDAGJ@VNjZWV@r11RVwr5YVpRpf4stNUheZdU25XcrHeTFAF00mRJBWXlPI9zaJ4SyxwR7Xgdw9/LCb2wTVNlspKanmyFACD219nfuwldVUObMu/mqLCqunmfg7PT1dzqyk19JPzs/Ph@Mf5EfVG72m3dZu9ApaSW6rLXEQOK791h89Wl6HyikXqmexRmN782Szgbdh4fQvcmX0JM4Ww6m9vps8JZNWaf38FItzfpZMVqpPeOuWSyyRrAo4NQlMkpXXqdQJ0JvNDm76GBLWiW860Wfa2nIiHevTKpy1AmvjRKbLnE5nETyhZVgT55w9w7LkwenXjmu1r822sRhLHO5vbu2cZIsbMEwVdze3ssXjl08TGr6WwncKXsb3o53N7YOXEOFwf2fzeOfzvS93Xh6Cvxd7@143DN0YGMZ1YzC4fodnaxsNow@@4adhtExPf/tW79OHVTlLw8/HX/z44y/@m49/@NOPf/jjj3/4819@@/Mfw/dP4PtT/vzpv10v4e8vv/3nf/zxX/0heP4H@P57@P7ZL7/9vR/yL73/OXz/U8Tvz8U3Ase/LFFP4wcIoVwsZ9IwaKTX14EYyHcjBkn91i@//dkf/fLb3/59@P5L8f396e/v/Nns789/NP@L8X72x3fD/PTfwfd/4bgk7E//FffD5xT8v@Jwv/37H3/3f@P/fyH@0PmHH3/3z/FHvPx3v/8X/@njb/wfxWL5L/71xx//9OOPfvbxR7/x8Uc/@fijf1r8@Hv/WitEf/4YSO5v/vQX@P@zP/2bf/8L/P@f/8e/@dP//m9@638ixx9wx//1L/8t//3r3/jxX//oX/z1b3w75/fHd/5@@wD/b/8OfB6ez4fgeUi5PtXn2@@Un1@lNsJUgAboRHJWBBnu6cgA1TpWYAXxAx3m5//s4@/9JtDh7wIkvP238Ab//AWCfkIvX301FpYhBVzNfPUVSLNfCc3mqyjQTxj7kAdxs/DkAwB8RaH8wwIoSPR/QCgAYwJKgo0lTiC43I97//Lbf/FH6B/ERN/fjOIrSN8I7BICf5BF/Al2vKAYUdifYNf9@Isffvyjf/rxF3/w8Re/hXxbXVnPbmZV7R6rHwCWHgCHgKsPgQNADfUaUD8XY0VwLG6glSqmZd68gUZYBFeNsXSstAxvMa1Obg3dEBGU1TQ3DmXQLATfYWxlHd7QXJSBATPDgzIQ9DSDV7BmYsMahBEo3t3K0Fkvo3UJ9d4a4MVIPE62UQYRnQ2fEhaIWcscsUa6NuQRM@hRJwwMM4ReR3GtGM@Ua9uQYG24zRAXIs/E3sDzTa1erg3riO4bygLgyDyFJAEKr4bNDOvfwHuNcAJ8bLj9DWSlXMtk6mXwqVFRKbVsg9LUSlQ4KnuGUbnRnzFccvf4CWOfxbVynCvmUJVMQONvJoR@TPapxxB@lkmL4tC/dNI3jfGhnYZUP9yPhz9Gb4ovAACvquJKLfiqKubmCQQPOaoMJQuPDMcANZcRlr3Ag4SJTCxD7ZuhF0gf8vApnw0@kCI6LM7S0hK4Nurx5XjjADQj5l5WPF93cTKJBLsKi6@ux9EbV77w5XxLh6RApbfT8KvB/84iLWGlklTTsaUkqtVJJlNSM8vOipPghZAlpLc0FSBDgOwzCMHvkyfghhqiZ@gXS4TxuOhO84Ygc68wJZaiK1YUUt4NEFhY7Ll38dQZgnidjcez2iqfDlC4bh/72qlUat9oK2sxeNL7AG93EfeMQGvhba057IRY7/UblVsa0A2C3GqsXheTn0wDH1aN1Y93TiDayQHTioVcrP4VG@bIZHnLoNlBUL9ZWSuulFZKxeXV1dJaUVtZXV9ZLZWXgcWtFkrFora@srJeXl@7pXw@AS6RraSbpY36P5n6/Ff/ZNZnti9@YvWhquaLlPmaVlqrjmqQPHnF6mQB4ZrI6EbFtZexM1rrdYMzzJCb2I2KlL0AHxZbiLEF8IKPehvDGSAm5uz3DqpifhYvGuNztHGtBKSjxM6AdDg20Yb1Okjc6t5u7ODggFYb8vlH1Wznujm6Daw9cI1YcZk6z/bel3vHewcvctt7xyAGf82Ky1DDg8EAjc7Cah7rRz9V@o0hfTwC3vdI487SaugsoPMEt6S@gOxDa9tsH9d4@g47cfhawqdGK7YhNlPWYzRVdgqtdB7D629OcdFtbCMfhM/GtdXldw5vuQ5oCN8d5qluX/KgbZNvowuCnul4RJ7XM/3uHIiX/R5ujDLcvzMMO70mZBCt4hzgKfy4luPMAlhjLw/nlPJ5sMkdp51plzuAH@19/uwk8jzZ2dx6FltlTw9ebE88SgKoxPZ3dk@C1zUeKqOWAhRf7@zvT76KRwJ7Nap6i6y0ls0C04YffGbpQ8/c0msJouXuuGBkKQ8quj1goJI2cKNF7anZrpeXV9ZKa6uFdW29BMUdsZcJ/cJY6jAYS@u6rz9eVfPlaudwHyrim8yLQa/qGkApRh@12/pO7Dkue1vX@PYN04s9A72yh5fD4EVQfgz33LXxKlO0BjTxTtFBn831hAd6odM1L7rAV68dCRBr6jqD76d@IH5UpYR6utPD52mQ31SINQMc51rNDivEcmSqLK6XS@X15WI5W14vr5S01VIpqxWz2lp5bb2Q1QpaWVstl9a1bHllfXkFmC2EltbXYgngTmYnn4cBRovH6WnaLTwkewNPG3dy3XoswY0wjL1P6SBlKCyhJxqB74DFDYgYx@t1PJ9W9qbNWhzvoS/gLe@AVmctltjd3Srs7sbjT/EFzbJbhXi8jS@lcqGw9jQeNyhkC0aFYjzu8DgQBGA@fykUnm7F4wOOAHfox@NdfNlZRfE3HjfxZWtzdxfTeYsvRYwPYJc8hL9Y8mUNwGx8WV4m@TkefxegA7hNntAK5XQHXzBNDNnlIVsQFo9/LvNTKACGIw7HMTyTZd3cjMf3@MvmJoZ8QQUv8ax@D1826ROPu/AClBiPX4DjwjUMOx5vghPpMR5vgas10sEPjyXHrdy2r8fjI15BWEXx@JCg9dZlHOQ84Y/JPHv2TO/6beOCf0Yuf7YgaxBiDgc7u83PP29eXDTd0ebO50cY8sUXz/S3o4HbvGiKaM0GfByIAyGXvdHkB/K412jo1syQ70GIPRHSGDUMzFtDfwd5Ep8LTKTX@AJCvoCQ4YwPxwafHoA28fO0B8@nepNC5IdC6DlsNuNVJFR/1DfQWIUdhy48zvb0lutU8X1YW0ymktnR6WrhvErerJdSbgrVWwztpOiKMuSHTLkZnQ5rhXNgWGtFuTcgFT8bFktmPLvYewycrbKoP9aKK5lhZTH9PnWWbSiPi1q5gictOp0kS6ra49W11@lBPF7Bn8fLa5X3qUKywBj8ZJXTtfPHa6VK/OzxYzV@qsHLWkbPFytra0r1FgrvwzjUHPhGo5FiqWtDv1QUzB@KIpRRtMErN/xO5xEVz6x2UsPssMZzwEZKdVjTgLX6AxiICpNIU23ctT7AW3c45guoiuHjQgWNhKm4tl6OQ0byeWUDuRHyD3i@ETMBr15NOMac/JNjFZVfHaaVV5Ucri9vOJ0GXWTC3kQhURZ9hdtAaAuoXLJFwrpXiZ2gwEq3ZjM8EaOJlxXSRmhQmPjRPIzbA7S19VisLqQ2djyCUb2X2zvIvbQ9vWNURQBudM/t4k2rjpvDexX9sRC@H1t6nRhDP/fMwEVYLem3xTdm5naGeJO06djVG/WVeksbtHErJ27vN9tMr9XBpbdTlAZkXrmmgjTq9Vqj1jN6fX8EqgAJ4vUgMgyG7CnjkLgrRC6Mb9SeQvkKVRvPszHwdWmYGMbqbdy2/7T29GZQqQDsbdWo0VWx8US82nls1wZU9kPDxT0cewcwBhu4WaLVfXO2g3BbUJU3t2rdZXY1yMSex2shWJZP@bnB/IiARq1wW72onaL/B/zZUOPxc9AGPpyDSF4rVEcJveYNmvx@p0ITNIfV6hD8tLWVapc1a83Xw6pb64MsXLWgqvg@miVa0KhXCfyDBQNhI9eALnhaLBazxcJ6tqjBcAfDIATDdw3eV@CrwRfCtbXzxcWUlYozFs8WhoWcltUMLes7OzZUaqFSwbqFVqFXeOpKppi2Um2H6RsqNRL0wipmCZhAl/XNbDcFsY4M3eLgSuYdSC5o6K@@gxpwl1Lt3FPl8Uq1nXrKGgp4wJAN3yJbXalGWzSlVDu11GulmlpUap7xjqsmVMD@IlQlV1KWvEHvtLC4qmVv1IZ6a@mev6StFSung6VTVYOyFT5cbMR/UI@fQ0XfxkCfiU4GgDBQBT/ZUbn4EAoAoV8fZT/LgGbR1otVARLrC64BtZfCu0X5er5UMrlWTCaVZBWgFsGbuI9yQywiCYwr@Uh7HAcBJF6JrxchPGQ2UzngitiqFkvcxtqm12cr67HETez25nYjuobse2w00jOqfH3E2EUGFPk8zW/mGgm2SC41VycrxmZt8@JosyqgN7e4GhZZ4RFjZ2Lno5pf/NRJ1cxG/TV/nuFyAEgVhM@mY52yczGLXFyGMrcj71A@7ybGK5VPk@c3MvX8WSwexz4ppsZS5ZIiNMZvEnRmMdu6kdc/V56juslSeoX3ttNz5ZsXpnVTXlbrfFkjS3yTgSrBJUT1/DcJoK/bW6pqsYAnlrAduZYHlEIfuBhw9FIpjkYCg/WP11@vvS6/fv7y4OXBLntSqJQr5ahcf/Ykm9WSWnKDPQFJ0jzagbx@YE5J@8b@gpYrJaqJSj@5vJJcHotWSwxrK0EZtXpd1TaK7DEQJ6sAM@loq2rhQ51TWp0CVosQ8vE3f39luFGG9yIIahWoxVKmWK9r6SJTEh@//Te4K7m4Jl3a6lriPMGTWFlTwE1TWEUtUc8Lb21NUxKeyt8g9VLC@5AoFsqJrQMxMxlfhcpIrCdiifLzNx8Y2wBVpN6@uDCL5MqPrx1aqnyjbsA/@watJd@oi2@AH3jeUh6X0qwjsNT70/V6PU0rbJL1DO7QKpbIuHx6Wz3nGjxK@Gmb/gwvjX/G68Aj7XnwLt/gNb1hsFJdY6AS5PMff/P3isXV//s//s6Z8qHxofF9YIvr6@urWjHxt9OffHohxtILmyzJT/Hjoyoe5hvsXkuOXTGKBqv0grp9fLD1vZ0THFYNW8fNe1sHL3IYhLfbh9sPW5ahu9ZIXG8/QigcjU@2DpnjspfbhxTnFW08JV@yO4lUlvbaFXGXWPaKabllnKYt5Qsrea3EQIgqrFWKq0wHNuXhQRPCtYRRGRVry@mPuDqX2lIo8sImwmDYvgnqtWdU2OeH@xSD2EB6YXvn@QE7eLH/dU76cv@TZ3vH7Phg9@TV5tEOlOP5zjGLbx6zveM4e7V38uzg5QnbfPE1g@CjzRcnezvHiCAfQxaHoiavsEC3YhveyMujHOqRgjXm7TmtS8Mf99fdvp7HE6vHvW2868rAq2HG/Qe2CdpbVHc73lzgohxD9Hq77cZwx6vZYguosS2kQSTADbfdgrfGSoOv3hfc0iJrrbxIrrFW4YW9vLHGrIL4Y9ZKb/mILS4untnxYHyIFiNQHaNeuLkD/MI87f1gZyG1usLSoCoWV5Qw5MXB4UJBvi28OjpZ0IKwo@2FYvCyt7uwHLzswNtK8Lb7anuhFLw93fzewmoY7cXWwlrwtr2ztVAO3oBIF9ZDnC@2F7RCTFbWFYhtC3TXbGp3b3@HpQFIqY6FogUQHRPeUBEpkLT48SNY5Sydvu46WdJCmqMJ6LZxH7QEH4NaQFnvFOv1PMvSTh9@QIoEYIgWC9QC3b1oZQVWPL0NBo/YTWwBC7SABQL4Bdz4jnBsscaKCoPghQ7XcVL8QM8si7/0aHvrZx7bQIm9DsSQpePgaJszxDDETdmxhVuBMtUhK2mHls8TqAY5jbtxRcG9kS9e7u/zxPokoqbiBMm4vDoDp9MHbFBE@MWigy9vHN4s1BZYVwtC6MDbvGO3Y60Zm2xNrAoo58JCCxCM1@6VbmUZCl1ZXMeAePGFb3sBYAgGdwFcfFNoKtXCsl4YfosypGBl7hzs8hLiSogaG29lhWGiVFMUzDfUfPjA5NuZP/7qjr/aSY5bIOfZ4vh4TmsIq6DfgtyNSxB08gDFXECKyWQgNhSHwiLlWoBKhy8/qEDmsg4JFZLs0SPKxwa8rScpCYyXoRSZiiCIQFQYVR8iC7K2SNlVFvJp2t@FC4/o0GEcR/hh0c1RcMgKcNbJjE60atALg@ZcsEGZrU4wZBHUaWNbg3u52IB3ZI9AyVnWhG6SZTJQW8VAVPCyzMiyDnhP8NSGaQPlGm7IEyUpQGek1n@xzVuInyhE/tyDSgx8r0INBsziEXZfIvSFhaYLyn1VQgE/JCigWySaFFYEh7s73tE2RUvz/oJkibEfEnNvtyLpiMcGchCURtWKh0BwWhHFJc96CDSFXyDD/lsD9JwkObJMRkAEVCbAdsbhVJXD3Uq6vKcQO5OlWPzkUiBbnluKnQcW41crBQxrIYlAKYDFpwBvBqDpZ7w1i7NQwFhIKKg03w0FDKAhLUEfH0PwgPgw5Ibx1U@PD4N0ZbIrQ7@FFuRcgUcZf22Nv7bHX7H7go/ONjZYcQVUmSa6tFVw4WEArAyONueV4xE7469k/6kxQ8bpBByYpwA0h6ySgyEBTjNj5CA5D2/B0Xt4L1uNbe429l7snIyHIr6c1xAZ7/qObVEayjiYyBCGeyl8UYIcpTpYCVzeTB3yNLJUn43jk6OdzedZyJ/CNsIeMCkDwI/oCWMluJUpgK9ttGA8bmdZ6niTpRX2CHOWZcKWgC8PTsJyPANQzU2xPegXKakCBwnex3tSAntkbEZS8RRLKezD2RkMqYU1pvX6H5Z7y/bacpuNltdQ2OV4AhlEcHnJYF7wrsmFDYRs83NLKzMTe1sosBV3mflGFyTuYcGdxk/lusWxjYZFufu675BS5lUZnl2IvEUc8ALj4rhoc7cUSWMj0gH6YjcGPxzOyWKYIfkcyZNCpYDF89I2PjUv90m043lReV42KNHpPAjtNXYSNQbjzJ840WLQtEzUQ@nuY7aHJvGRPOAoy3oONJqJrpbTpydam4TZG948x4JfOpELZ2jpoGhj2LccE8@Ow3NscBbdDU90zcUObNYDPZfsydxEbeLxb2JPOB19w0/Zoz2psYVWa@zW68hl2G9AS@rbFypQd8e8YKra6lj6hQcOq02uN7Hj4PwPTMEydahBSkLbb@haoST0bToAFzOH90kfvvic4WmiqNtLI5Jumf6IFt@ikEULcA08cNczrwxgO3hSktHOxbga@yDVLuqHZqlxP9qXO6Hw6p5nuBNabZ9HlOSTTz/Bhc1P0nlBN7jLtqG7TdPHOx0a3DDc4ClKQb4/rlDRugxBdbgWg5Md7Wjnzp4@xLeJWFhjZBkL5zZRSYAU9Z4hVah0uk8oSZhk/CWCOd2fj9vsXfy6UI/hbpvGGF4H6moAdUW9bIoRfeaR5hYAAd8hDrTz1d5JQxynxfWmsdmlOWpkpJar8q1f5SWI5F/kfFrXRLYJ2cczOfixmFDUK4fTcpyUOdT5oLXhP6JC0uVFmHXE1qch9nTlnKtFBdJHZIUHcR5xSngUydWjsEIXxCgR0MAD43Gtk4NMlxcRd1zDIABSUaU5fEKD@TXT3pyWaVq6fYmuKtf/WdpzW5HGooOCIuVAPTAoi1AK@bwilBuiBrp9mNG4GzQLAQgtXzbzSxu7MxkRMQ5v4SBpFMkxDXHISQ/PX22lwuC0lCN42RSZEoefSOoAuLbTQXOB4454QnjIQapaBRAUPognGLZUwSOlroW1gehIUonkAui2Kr1wEZgR5jPL7s4tT2qRyIHEmtlZ5RIOQp0G2TrnSc3nhVDfSrQwY1HDypFyEThhaPdBEreMjqA4GMaIRrjKPVUrXHwNqIjxejotnMM/exx9qXBrBHYoA01AyEIU7MZ4NMJE5oJMI2g96DqYVEh61FBolsImNIkWmQkSA/ozM5MZa6cI8lMT601jGart1IxQYENBiUTVi7onGBL0oTW4fYF1uFjK6zo2UUWgQaCBRuYaXgNqPJRz2EASwfUxSOCcMnlfFhVale@yEwZuCgkrJeCqt9MGQprAN3zXue6bQ8NKAcNs4DFhfQZeQg7r97mDIAKZDLyxsSnvgl8tLqYg1inB5cvn7BFLaRsbqTU1RV6flRUl6IwiejESPRIZmHS9zlLFdGpZRl7ByIByeRzBymwERY5gJZ3SJIKiQKCVAAMXMQjJZ6CSEdWOIy5HEAd4z8dh8LCxGamnixntfGOjjIprxHMicnF21tPLmSJE5qgXMuMhHC0PiPifj5cIkC8XI@NIBMVKZhlQ8KQz4wFhqhMBQaLRNFfOZw5OvzbhRRqf5eBD0fHMY8M9LWN5kVK5pa3PwN33XeGJ50726fTJ0I@TdBrJHGQE6pKQWtfAmaAsP31UDFpQf9WJUTFi8SUIZANUCRKPmWVv7xrrmp8@2CFwh06O4WUGdTXLyqCGAEcBjlGGyMBCqA7Mi0ar1w/gYCguK9yMxQcwSuSFg0tJrkC6b5PYL1MiNsarDw@SAnzi9EcaQ3j9piBCY3/vKT6@3DlCM8Dei8@hCRewHFkW/spiLnKMQRG3dJvfRWD6JmQBeBtXaERZeVONp4@eMn2BTSIX8JPYeUQqHUIwHllIh0QXpt8wHYGNV6WkI8OneqQDEgOAslIFPYNdG0y3sDpG/GD3Mj9HkWbyKDZVFTiCiCKDWENYZydHmy@Odw@OnlPNHTY29w@fbSJmUDBbutsG9P2ujh3Etg2LD6pBfcZw@L3Ae0mwTHpTngzGb2xBWH5kLK88AGxQSIN8J3OE5eVEPwXPvWdFII4SQINQ0Wgb/Rm4USEPwERhvBkIeSvyXIuhUORp1khIA970SCj5aB05HdWlY3h20gfC9um4Npvzk7zE9xS0TDo2lnouylEXRC8uPydzuUiH5yMdeYM@WsSMdjxa/XqrZXi0aCysfUBpWB1KRHCWSEWBz@zSh/yDG9yDsVfgoLODadAtBHJvKOaOC4sgPfK6@04ybkRA4likjHQjxUoSi0TK/Cz/MdHRHBcZ5yXGU3vLU3sLqXGGy95OCmTm@enbMUFsVvWYsnrectlYSmZcPAnsY9RyHej0XhfXcpMthHMdajBsJlrJ6IzGeN0j2WSPZC8Oe@Js4e5uoUxU7LhEJgaccPwUCnO7DdWWmrJtkDmetK@Bi@3PX2zjGl9opOSzN1LFIHiilAaI0xJOsk@cGJpLGYgJuCFNAZyK5M5pUAnwpQRCpsr8KBFZg6aWhVXAtIFbhDNuoqwkSjqeUBQjnshWxSjstmUnJ8hwMHPbk7NUCIS@fBY1NLXyuUmeUBmddO5wjVAjhYQyKwVwWVVVIYLC7Rok0wC7xTJQ9kx/djHK08UQhZMymcnN@sjqhFvjrABBP4DeA74y8erMckfKIWf4MLISKVihKszCcpnCy0O2rC0vR9Y0HLx6wVZXwyUPuCWErRQL4ToK3BzCVtdj38lOFtoTOD1ixxENimSFNIOqO8iChmVBJ@aPtolDP@aNq8VD/hhVA@EqzTVYT7BjMTR4rIc3mjQNvLkDL6L2mTbUcrEFYIonkTth5OANgBcD3dVt3@ATx8jIPWfgtgxKkCLS5Uqux@@LoRtTgOPTPX3ewDW4ARh82k6LrlxBHBQPWnrQo1W9WRQYrgwX1zaZvli9tEA8R5ADZw11TgTSUzKHuqQNXoWCJVCPRiMLr0YalrH2uOlFuIokrpzsFyiXJ/saDWnydHXMAFWvIBWqY@6OLYgKnhpmSB9Pi1M@ZZcMgEPWP8s0OD3IcOVU6uECDR9jpjV/83yGMYaoqxUdg4ZYYxIVlelckRN7xAHkvE5L2iE4ED2G5zQ8ES6ujWIN4n0rJreFM@IRJEXQKEVDiotUp7cu5RYhCl4I7pcgeq5B71PAgxITs4DBnK@AQJJXOISY8J2EwP7JIYZRHJAL3lHTYrkhQSCOYBIP2TdRiNTC0a0IvQARcL2WxC6efz7RNrsUoo9SonyebTKnFKRE@vJsMF5kAYali4BBpogfpYM1lBzs5WE4mScBKfdkkLor82OpPTTzIrkpoLGaeGDWg4q4Fba6WUghcs@54vdKiYkzKWZG2ocLSdCIghCIZqnfC1OFqAPJFXjumpEYXGaWcSQnoRCxkmGa5QiowJEuyjUOkqEHZs5wscKsgnJKlkWVxaQWpDseLLNPQ@N4WUW3iJZV1aYLuxYprFw6MVZYEUmWc3rRmg2ODt7iRYvKcECJi@UY8c/aWfZZGydDhE90jJK1MYv/jS/giHTI17WwRwblC/JKKwGCF95XxdwhsvYovWM8xFuQnRwP@achQENwx67Ky0x4rIUFIc6A0DMWr6gIs3NAzhJFpwP8GhfD0Tbg/aLEFFIMYamxbzgeGoLoSrAIsAT7QHweM6AEsHjRSRQ2QkWCM491UkkdGJDJiPGsNmYNDleFzCXEKBbBOyPrLu6MTzxlOhcjDOPD5GwcMooY7sP@X41mZDQ3I1gdNEckxrpgzoiv87r9VWdGQ9mtLyQ3kLv6Rfh5JwQxIb@VClIOSPVDeSHQDrg@EJUNhKAthUE0bOHNe6k@X@@RZZD6XPhw2eQ7PsHX6roYk5Y1RqPR@rkoQ@I5LEbUon5EiZnOJrUO1Wift8l4vqkhyRASYOfFeNQ/RWT5oorTgNyZ0aZKNYaO0coNssZV@YpGEmXxPAnSU6NLGrHh01h4nLIM9aw@rniQqx0IhdnrWwa/B1Dbb2we7IW3QopbUQzPQS8v57gX@Wvz0sxzwNixWIuPt8VDP8eV9zyksfMShjJcRe/n2LHBFysY4va/N6ROGgPlDUbCZf02AHc6IPHaeEmPvDRKIPBy0cxCsO7xW0lHjtMMc6/jbbigk/IMZCnvHmT@Aipm0KQrXFq67xkjI48R800Lfno6bsXPg0qexxLmD2xjH2If4x2Lubf6lR7bjmSMrk2aSJU20MRUtB1RCF6Hy1ePoA3Bp4tRmg60DfRcg1ZKCCWBttw5tjViNq5r4tfGM7oqQN4NiZcL4iU5YlKHljzwOxlXCuurxOw9McJRPBy/czkIKykxfqZ8hYmLC6tAzajr8Ohja1om1mTwjjm@iILr@eN@LdxxcP86jWCJRz4fievYD1n3MWuNB21qgGqft/Ijn0fzaN/CiwWvdToEgW2trBVWK4zfYEpkiL2Fbn4IJXZj2MeT2XFhAI7jMq5lXBkWW8Zm/NL0BgB47A@gSLFE39UveroETC1XGCYT2XhA@vXYMqUwyHGscZ@OjgNGqFHTXVBMC7HR/XFiVMHKFN5iXDAU4Frw85g1Grbj9FkFHG28uJEGA7yKQ8bAc@P1bBMj6Eo91VQew7MCT8g6bbiHfoydvxYsysf1RI7JTqGbnzM5QRGvxqgU0PVrPPdVGR9HDgSLzOjAgM1nNWBESLOGUEa5lQCgcQxLcTiP2z1p8lyCtJ29A7TaUILQY/upIASLyDdhKdW5a0rSLLKmBFgCLqJHwqR1/fm8tIwkN/GMffnyNMlDyWqU4u7QRMRHvXRQHXL9QoevPtmgjQ6MNi5SdSrYAymyVmW3EhDXgKCEgytL1KRcOYASpotzM@GKFKj6uNTC7kIbycDyPZDUcEhmOC5FikGJ0qTjbbBuZTJYO5dzWOBfK1RlbfArOYL2DyezHvHWXKCCL9IFHzfiRttUvMUnYmiWREwwjeUVBy9BI0QdHJcY4lOcHshjnBqENZGMptnAoMozym2uwCxQ5lRpSMmyIbtA6ztXn7JsJF7xmI8Y389fyI5qWjXY9G/Yg94NKiNZHmXQzyLwLTOA21dj@Cs0OpcnHvRuGCWIrSMjp0vlyOtU@qNp46aQZdptlVJu0VmWnMWDHDFN@zPXYp3ZiK9yCqoI/Z/zYaLyWTue5enhlAE5NOkonmfD1HglBrkejpzL1DA7AtbBUkNa3UlaB7qFcZ5eR5EgWngp5mkEg0E7bEPHeccG1l1KbqtgjWENFKTGqIY2PL6pAQVe3i1oVSzCVxgAqioCgobKpLBL4VTNwPqGmQyGg1I3Hj7oV1DLlvGnwrH1CD@PH8V/G@78oXpoDLONkSLXpUCMxihNVRAsT7mdKi5l71co71R@J8o7VR9BeefUR1De6fr8TuUNLMZfUUFgiKEH6jiosj8GjRqv9JGe3E7xmKFnIRyhtr@ejD3o4wlyE7Hp@J3p2E6/73h4DMTsHPA0Z2SCwiP@kOZjnkYF3KAg57n5SCsXoOvhYSpejHdx10F5MUVuPFqYj18gT1rcti3GaPJAzOtk0Q9e1Yl3SEARQ0nUS7LEoHyYFOepXJwAse2S1hfXWCSpapBxKijXwRhFDkqvMP4awREpOi1fhNzIKFhRCpsVZYByB8abjIJ@s6OIWhf8cTwW1jqbGUs2IsYWqyulJERsJ77HtaRQ6o5H5poaxJ2BXCPyRKDHBvbeYUYSOG8MsvQmM3KUBlVsj1/3vSWuxT0U1im815Yu8nadwUWX4ep3lAH5zbMYoeOgdI/SJUj1eJ70AMinXZHL4lJh8QP7cZ697DNQ8vfkfevPD9kWCv5NujCd2wJSkWFCrLBaWJCy00Jo0l4gTh8An3NDH7c4hMlTm0UysI30AFl4jpY4SP6IyGlGwnIQU7VAAonrvo8nkKBkLa6Mx@KH0fo4DRNGRAlAblwgYWUhAJ2dWU7GkdxS7qLZ3QdSmZXbwsxM0p6EyUw2DTT1Fe7IHLciTtpuIDuYOuZm2/g7aL8gVT57DXr/PaQJiUqqzPLL60HJbdHN9m3cm9/DY9Lxrl9OqaCBA8oXeCuvZY2yMzFfoz2Oepd@DboXqcoIl8mJ7HRBn73ChUYzY9OMW1eHpqKtA4gIckCilbwFEfHQLdnsOamjQWSuAHskyuFmWp4Np4WzzDLydE3g2YhG20ORVUdaoXymcHuD6K5ylrBt4q1rWPKA9crskD2atMWu2eK7MrYOMSuu8W5gulzZxtzkoC1p3Q@QwlbXwDtKARZPhguxq6atQrXZvup0mPduoLsGv@c@k/RigsfzkeZIrMSZlKMEg6qOARPl1aaFkAgwip@4v22CrKS9Dk01kufRYh08oCjpiVODhM0I6zZq@0GrSY4BvwoMMjA8W5wXQw0Rnoj6nWWdgYW82OnnMAw54Xhho28oWDYXa3xn1lgxIy9jQJyxjodGMIplKG6AIUXDuBiJOae5H3x9ChqTmgOscuhAx4rUb1BpUJVj9TY2vUObgkL7BQST/TyF9OZJmA6utXANoUJgnIKSpUSm0dJQPI3Vdmw1ipmDTSMGOARTHtp@tb@n9mMoANnIe4DB9Pt4baq8u5yyLrRP6OlUSiRkURTgA72B5eu24Qw8a/R3TQixBTqEWcjO4DWi16/F67g4jmoY187yeMIJ28sf0HI3XJuAijow7@J@BUPiJ4LVYMP1HDHOMktsg/Gy8nwznCZKnWDYvgjDwVGuCZgIgdGJoaUHlwn4tMcry5cNAOuk7WK2n6N4coGd3vIHxES7Di6u4DfaZnGpQw/YCPhTkyDDxrIgcqdvuDwxoLaRM2ByfPadyP5FYJDhBkITEhVDH@FH3ozFQrrnAwngQdwRVPyO70gcYL@QcQAPb5bnw1vTEDYKHNz47Bbd0AopULLwRNwm3wMXJvidU@OzcGjzxSQR90S8Qi5OR8NErGR8nX1qUej3ilT0J9Y/kcgsbV0SlhOUWNuPMwm0qmLaLCcVWLNKCy1SZg1XamzgDgvolwB6ap4v1nCuha/aINsZtuI1EIihu60uFAnay0SC8V2qp7bZpmoDHQ7N3sH5DB4D9Hhgm8IFaHvQaxp42wfVV7BNk@Y90EgOIKkQtUIph1svTeJwZgbo@QyXepL9uK0EfYsnRXoJKj8AGNiRcAQVeSL7pagYfA9XNgW100mJVzSFFLFa8P1UeKrauTxkYyqoeC6P4whUvmJ1EqN2B0YlNJ5NbAlDg5cfWeJ07biXfOYIzW7E@X3dJLs3zgXyBcsYSVr0cJLfC8P4TIY0zoVnNVF/xoGlq/v3G3klNfnAFC2@oYdvnAormM/hVcNFy8Fq5AKnLWBhLW6ByosgXBnF4/KZS87YA@KRc67chsj3BhWiW7dEXdeiXYG3tTBl8n1trtUR0tUYbQhIQREILXOO5ndhkpRpqISGoHjmuY5Dmc/UJFhVbHdSoz63qP7zfMrqE7Ri2PWC7I2cPmo1Th1hGsEi4VZkqW5abm/g68nGqp/ONq8Fp9J8t3ojjsHNqVU2FOu7aKfVkK/wWpjQvxkv8SmKpAsLo0@pHaqLYJl4aJOPEzWLbkB6R7AYsMhpY0LLk4yxw7v@jK0qYpEnP8MFhneGJ8SI7RvwGjWGe74STNeLDur5Oc8n2omM9CrnPkDfs/qdbnkODJJcUrNGotd7NF/4aTMxsgfy5EW/aw46mBWc6Yc44QaV6d0pi52A5dDSXD7hz2uKwGnd4QBx8P6vRFYLylNC@K4VgKItK2KGX0Q8lTZxRC@WUXeEjYyXgKUbIllRBpEfKgRNeO@FR8@RVvW5a1zA48jEHLW9JMpLwcx3LrbNjYmHB3svTnaOGkc7X@4cHe9QTFrIH2woHvTzZCnzrvHEAlvgTXrRs@5ysVeuCeM4jjh0eBxq4Mctx/fZLqi7BqjjlzrE1AdGbO6ce3F/fthLz3ArPP4JF@Zp8z2tNPZM3CI0wKVKUL5rroDz6eGUp3DihzEQd/ij0o8SsTzsLoY8E5g5D0H@iT2p6dCZrAQhdjbgkOJ0/GuUAIU2MT7HHFzAlRNrbCU0mhzC8xKCAxFQAIBwXHU7ytGdEtG@ChVvgMyJYiTmlR/cDrr3VoEd8mS3KVm2zcuFMqRuOfZFTJyeEMkBSW4waGXxxoqKrGLaFARJ4LoF6DpU07xEvEB51A/yWq6Q//UdaRBOYv8DnVbwHbbkf8d93tP79GceCjdr27482CQi49xO7KEbOwtu5g662UfQjW@om0ioKBL6btvJ5@8mF@iX/4F3kM/ZQC5yt/L3s2n817uf@8HbrH/lMxb@/rfhzCTgsV05knxnLjG9/fVt2Pn/yq6RT9suct8uin/cOjF764Q4JfJTNk8k00lafYySx94BN9ijqSkw/3hydbc4o21CJpNca2yhbXAs1/ii@fCQLbES@WGL6MdW0I8tK/87Ww4/v6wz9gKExZ297PgTSh3ZHDFW0MInrYQPTh@7Z4l7dLX@7Vj@ZbrRZfu4pN0doewZGtKwz4nsji@RJm7z4QMbWwbOd7rwNb5E/mKFebC9Rax7jxrj5GJ0MXZImxmPObH8nRsFZ8QOTq70xcF//MzA8XMzBbVG9yQKuEJ1bEG80KMUiet2uv4mlq2HNRgaS@kQsagRX@Q1lca6wdP1aGzAvQfKZBuNoQyNsfNQjjeNbIt5iYmONrUnJJiB///LbquABPkGj3/cZPUPuMnqH3eN/OOukX/cNXLXrpHEYn7gufmmaedBNLOYeg3SP90qsn3AXj3bPGEnz3bY7sut77GvD16yV5svTvAWz8OXT/f3thh8d14c77Dg8lH6fGm4uOSeQdNvGy2DrPPFQmGFEeapWxdW2LHeY8@clnEFxLPh6b0nXf6Ssw2/zmPtXBnuyOHTQX1czOKLXRNkK@JzTdLihDuum0DJPZxHlGd5Yh7pNE9PXgkInY3ueAg2cPO5PZJBaB0XTSsFmzYA3gFfQKPzKVlaO41T6yS0tHNMVFzw@eQaBKHw@THbfLGNxxdv753sHbw4ZrsHR/B6@DUes8O29/DYmKcvMYgAnx9s7@3ubW2SB89AIcfQtkYb1u/KQg7BqVZal51B6zLXt1ArFG9j13okYjHbkbsiPJYc2OHxPW0gKZx354edosEJCHtp8@jzL1GqMd6xeBxP7uUXmSIXkDsQlgq4aQRSE1cDVAmGREtV4wypN2JLGFyly1RT5M4yiVyheWLTYPEtNCPihDS/c5UENokaEloE3IhKHgRbY29BQE4lk9kNQlmH1Mh6IFNDw2pHvmDUJ@JgVtQjE/KUVo@Q4omze3aLnw0uPYDu@apuStZ3OQAahIQHB0AbDHr4@qWxh0YSVhIQAx8Vf/BY5R5ve/3da5QacYOr8HiKkhAdBBFpRWpSnTVd3bR5O45ta@LcQfdapklRPILHQ3IsS5pcaUkcyP9ijg1nZQEyDlywAz1bKhXhtBtQA/D2rt7xPZaqKWgNBhXEsE2@UuvC0kHdI7uwixuWrnAZASVbxhusa@LmplDgpNOFpQrTHLHxfATxtsXAbzw0HsR8OpUirtujQuOCKZ1Lu/dm4OlUBr4LGkCkRvkFHivU9/nlo4jG6QhSTnkOUCRe9vRNFB7IuT1oGWMRhK6Temu@f6@ISs6GUSJLfCh3wQq7t4NeHydCrvEMKjrmApQYWinZxdko3oap8RKEc8M9XAzhYgbf1OpjqUWVB5miWIkjEkV5fk6qTZ02w92bKlE8XxscsK9@cGYUTX97fFseTZM0UU0OtDkPz3PGRQx4spOLx7x0GC4sGvmUE5S8KrFYyDu@YV7@9HW5Vt9@eqZ@8yZ7ns9fcLagt/nkBV@UyKdZSCWH7hGsnaTVgLKnCaQxb9DE2HI9I@eW2MslMhBcuiYI308a1SCMm1Wn/fFqukl/8vzwocZjqbTfhEho4HVTIXfLslOZZJbinDNFIAh5J2QWT9aVPlnCGfDrJ3hZB7ZC9f9p79qa2ziy87PwK0ZDWZgRgAEBkhJJcCjqQq@VkkSGorKuomAsLgNyJBCDYAYSYAqpbO6ppFK1WcebdfZSuXiTSl6Trb1UJQ95t//D/oL9B865dPf0DGZAeu3ap@CBBLpPf326@3T3OX05DTUyxHGEjtdopeXzNZq3a9zQg5GlIPQ0bm6Fb8sHFoRE0cfS26P6gXXfLe3aVUlFnUlVpyWH6LJErtmiVPRQCc1XC3APl8PB@H11uM2l3PH08KXQHi5F@1K8VUr5WDwtaVhXh/2DJbA8uf1GsFD2cj4wT5KLaErSlXCWb6xImb8kx28ttB31PYDBuXcUjGJQLbfJcIAe4ixeFAfWKIGtw8QK0bPjh/tHR4ZJj2luQ1oY9/DZx54YBhH7uvR0xPeQabBzlNIkP7HyJEPEUzzJbJd15szKyxkqhA5SFvWhBov4ae@@PxW3I3hmIRUCL17zgChrLsndhRyDwhMBPD/Bk1BG3GhaAQuZxVzhyYed7NMgE9dbmXXj8JU/UsqMNxXOumipejzTgaQijNNB@xR3vrPb75usH2/LfFjB8n5/QgXGQ/hd9JdvPIOMR7hT7CRbcEmzyCalMyskpSuy7uhaXlLD/uoCpR6YmAtdWBvWhXIsWGP9@IZUc2hZE6cB3OeficjuuVjvlEM8hezoDWrHk56VnIJAyQQz2NjTpQKSN@diCqPaUPOkqxRyva/dIG5OJJdNPGMksBv5RO@ABr9xOz08pLOC0XZpVpWvJyueJRI5yTrPLIyMBOTbGxtrl2GnSyGTV74qNs8h6fEzOh@9bmuQ4Syko0IguY@elmV8LABLqs4FK7BnyQ6TSgiqTsackig7TUY6f8ALPzkNzBw8Py7jelE6V9uYpnjLRucZSUcnkoUyaF1YFZR7zULtz5dnhwPypfld//L5cWdDIlwPn3/BD84eBSMcKvFN8BZ7RQWTfDvEU3ERpuBX1JWnX/awR0h7YcTm60mTf/MON96R5hz3ouAVnut3RSonHA1gUDJxG8o5b48u3uIC11taMuU4vBMg0vplY@8ln1FZ5ZBeQIcIyKmBYIC4TIbBMP@6pe4XQtw2Hh8s8CufSKBtYLqqAos3iwbYPdu4qlCWYSUOA/1EBVU4SL5prcJvcTjeS/BHg5kKr3J4z3vto5tsEbojUN60RypsV1BOoB7wzJeKMAUxrdX6/VmLql1F3@VoUGNU0DuCGbAtB4EKvc6heKZKBp2ItJM4qMlBYEmpoBVBhROTH@myFHreqxY1ssHTAgAWy8bQHzQdcX7qriVsR1tc4Yi4ISG9N@wVqFFQxGIoOSXsoWtZIUIne37ToQOUYgBCmyxuWO5Ie36cQCeGcBhfa/IXCRUnIwbwr2BCsKoLL@Z8svcSJXzshd2JZ6gH3xNSSY5BVvB9KOPgXePo4HA/CY0ct1BHoVTywB6K4IlgjIoju2wZGjyYRGctDpQ/07FvPI6VEPxbEQ2DsUbEP9OxMgOCaGK3NC7e9t4aJzB5j1SjWD27KRpdlliVwekGk2F08Xb6lpp3CpqeAyJw15g7uEhwd6FaRE8UGrYUB9qLa597LdQrW9KtQpwLhVAuU@GbIxA3rlN93p4X5Ku@cvyEpoOeSYO0GhXRSwSOBAGqPNtjXDAIPaiO7pkiGdNetouvfKYYw0nJcRaCS8Yd2xbJPTkkLWZ2xUxKeZlsxZmwhCkcJ4QQK87NNnqB8dZ/G7@DLicVnPo309aOqm303SyaUZtiqNslaFabWjTvSmhl7hWS3xY6nGjB@D54IcYRHQJaTxvNXZbxBBnJ9wKZGhwkGXegBTrqBQlC7iYLhJR@EbGVzWXc9TKSZHMc98dFdnJyieEykmTnEjOdbIq4r6daoxuAdsYPkuCXFhiC2vya2XIgNgsZ53VWI51QiCKZMy3O0@J/dkYecphmCpDHpvxaazbF67p6sqX0yRrRORCF1yoExyByp4LTmh5eS4frU5KxqyVPU2hMpYgBMzVTXd4W7EkkEfQGb2pxt6JLW/w5QV1LTI0w5DQ1UhKhHNJKkpR7TUwLpEhCWhzOLBop98QkaSmbVBN@otdRU7xqvVGRlrJJtf6xgFrJQk2SltKkC@MaDZTJulcK7S1reePZOXqsDqdl5U297iTimUY6rYA@FEH30BUtQd3zT/3orhErWvTNAX5QaNc3hUdsGQYG/sYdpfpQAqlq6yyIbGNAHC00XcrPyJiXo3T1LVbMlfKYoMfXGWh@00lPiEJvBoM9MAlGpJIhDBo5i0lVTK8aTjWNjAZdRjJMY@UCfs5R@z1ZuWBzx6F9R7Ns2nOT2WokRlEokwwW9tHOjqwLJwpavpH5aQjmCSMYGUkMJw5a8klgTCIViksc5UHQ5cXOMmI1pLF2AuFN8ehmGgN3UxbLIhMCTPNyPnBDZRFjRC8BLyuUjiGNqkWMW1fGkAbbIkbl6nyQPZVVlneujMGGYBZG9coYKIGLdWquXADAnP@aWaKWqA@8FiVC2@VOUjQUZjvxq5MuizRVDbwvSAgJ@mnqVxYfQjHXZX2gmUFXqg80Ohbrw/K5J@3CVEwj9yovMNcwpb3QX9i4pVBegdV6XsO4EUY9mAic/kD174zOnzLRU4skApDWPdCIcbpnYzCRsDUdYX1IBYQwgf9WC49mtVq0MnR4dPCNo3tPWk/vPUEjaoXHKFy@wdMydFxn1ambEMWrLS06U@QaeNQCi1GgcViLI/4EzD7NIvRyLKZaudDo5iYrUJiTS@tFztB7Y7wLUQ7tDKYxkdJRazPQPBbxoAZ1s/LatGNKfQaTpRL22i5wQjQsJ4ITotGCC5qxxelfDPmEyovhi4gJO8YJ38kMmzq/L/DikpbQMCqvX0S/5407eJakopyWciviEXy03cg5FR65ECvoMYLWgF9Uq8Z96RRX3F9rD7ro8nbSJ8e35/6gfd7ptZ3R2ajQD13hnsYq9kN0clnAw1SPjvePnrUO8Z2u/Qd0cwI/DYo7fvRk/@D5McY8g6g1Ebx/dHRw1KID6kfPD4/RY2gqyNQJBUpMJgISRE8P3rv3WKPh36Zgki@EhGBvwj/hyqds@KPWlP7O6JpHmY9CtOgRHrqmgkkprGxE/rkXTOTjbeh/Qk7wZbx5gpsykJd81Zgc0li4/CniYl@nc42K@BhPRhGR0gl4K1UTdjIF05yHp5iAfBGFoLfTaXqHV5QxDi/yBSMrlRYvyGCygrjf1Q@pd2A3eTYbdi0JJxx5li@8IVDiblNxEvUrm8W5jV4lR3RoKJ24WIWZo0rOUYvZKUUNilPpBe0RI33ZtVGQF96Bim6UUCPEN1MoAe8gNoxSybcvCvoDUSIKRlV@P@rC0O7QJ2nE@zXXtDZit6Z8zhfyRwFR38QNHCUj/PNQ35QiARP7U3SZ4wRvnqs6o/@ysLzCbKnWsUJ@fF7e63bw9MgDYPheZLGjF/LZF8ud2O4SDLQwIt3iyTiAF3tjosCUIct4GDWgoqLxzOAbhGGkqgtK3sS/U@HatYsHaCwQOFunNU2OZXeUeEkojJiAzDxz19yO3djwtQR1cJgpdnSKWhbFBzpFPYvitU6xlkXx2UdM4vetUkk23q5R39jg08yJ9sxI/p8qeaUiaXfkUeg4MeDpyeVszCD7jCGoSy5eB9XnbADXObu9lLMk9Gf/Bdg6lkhVoUyY8SVsL0H@/I/MbV6hu0It/T2XUBugUDkRW158hRnXCx8IEZcsibukabSfLUEzTdmK2Wm/H0vEBzlC89nPEzTZYvOxbHdD1Z/c4boWp63FtxrSAD9dBHC/DECL08v@Rd5G@QIvRte3FYosQQzAJGs6ST1NkpXl26VZrup4tcwsazrJ6lWy/OyXIk8xf2VQ/EhR0FgrKjOT9L8THY2O5kOiLNKQKfFOzWG865tLfprkQU@WRX4Yo1OS5nK@P/92mu84ZSb9H2cKJyXQ5Us2e2bF//NVMdZyMb7FEJVKbr0VmaJUyqX47NOYD67edDdb1kk@/9PLU6/mp/7DOHU8ze/KiZu1BgmWHgLV8aBkJCU9UWjcflABKiSDG20aVX1O63I4F4sLY8kC1FS0uHGWjK7L6Flm9JqKToHPWcGSWhL61yPFaIdfGCTVKP5Ot3xZ4ZKRu66utdlcIF3bZWVdXDCHulE6jriKoyk9uymD41bCyFiEFrG2UPbmBdKCG5nGT9get8@GbXygNQyGjngBxA@q@@fBSx8nqnEV3Vw4L8M8a@irqNYEQHaci@brPTxQAawKpyJ89pvtdiRsd7uT88kA99BcYVehY6RqFV3GkSE4nJyHAhNn3PsTfwAlcFFTi1VEMPNGwCXNwqBKXyn7VNZZ2S5mWa3yuXGH3NBREPHWHfujiDJzF20BdPlECipk4e9otFKFxwvqFwTErmhdUZ7H/tCzNHp8xdUvawHkF6HkcqoGSUa6TjSMMp4AeTo5TyBciBanszEuxzgh3vixVst1rDkP5cYYe/hCiLod4YdGXfigI9cyCCJuEI2TKPXyus21RECHIJ7nSYr1cn0VMxphFLkoIs/Q6mR5u09ui@hSK2EQmqKmVgCNMIYX9bq7CqWDCMWXa/76xx/9o2lfVKsyjN7U8YdtsBnoRZIYFX8eB4fytwaP9om4q5jC/qcYm6F7Xtc/b@MLNZEGDcKVgwwNiMgXIGjotCoYwHgTnFqaLxiZIQpWtXrv4UPj@L2jg2/ibSheRCApSCVHIdg2zBJXO6VMxIuDwUgiJGGR5onIGIkkE4tUqlRIpkpM7nX6lnYCC2rrO39OtUVr@QGedOd@mQLEaJOd@uA6IZ6t1WFVQ0gJxnb4zp8xcjDi07PZwMHIFIIJX0ceCL9cirQWysUU2fn96gd/RdmJGyWg8@G6yrmedZ7ST7EnYkGWZLZSa@aWKpENVUIu8KVV9N2fEFjIj3TLgbBwTR8VFUh2sX/0dwZh4OYDtJ6W0kjglC4F@piB1O4B1VwuXuVSvO8xXs@nXQAdqDNLFvEJzJPOGC8NWVpw9ZLq@9UPBMdA70e4Z7Ikj1sJdguZjfEfestSWtEcee2r4ee28A91UHHNNQ@RJ6pMnI9@GXdTvZjsOpnl@5rWO1OsZRb4o19kSR@dMYfegx7AGVZvqsy@ksPz3/ytwp8Wrk0vEZhf//iTT@MyTnNLNs0tzydxb5oulmKax/u11JD0Pk4ZZmma2xQ/T2aT6LlTV/uZB/CzvHqfJit7mtflQfRVp59e0u3zQD6WIKrDTy/t8nlY35NYmZ09Xayc7j7N7eYSPaejp/Bv5bAJnfHf9c44XdbyuX0@Xyz@gcBR4cPLowvNUq0KDWeVVNsdo0b/0TMv/t9Nc6OPfrjUFisuLmhUAIdWU0L2kGq6o/f8i/Sb8nPWa@LQmnC2IEuk5VITuYBp0h6EGVm57teWVx2rDsy9jFx2f7NMCvNqdejxpfvJqIdWB@3fnZPlMabtP3w8IHtk/Da1JWjbYK7wbRtyT3BCLDdpBydcEB@EI59D0tRAD9A9MDfo/44qbqXGIWRvXEujDAJWia7RcjqaQrmGiLAkSrVmplHBdmpmR/hXNQKxddVh6worS5SR/MjGMZcO3t/9VI1IqpaCJHoKsnQ55r@IZqAjRrRXTh47hE6XD@0mfilDKhkqp4Dcqfvf9NEilV2@LqmR5SF//y/UROeFeJa1B@XBK6/k8R8fx8SKyZ0BtfGTvxKAZd@Kh4zcnP9SNnzII1Re5jiTXSGfnGx@8icminZ2JXF043IjSyDm2ljGo6fG82f7R8bB8@PD58e4IKM7RlQ2eL6hx2Y3j8tkwCYXCRZs2QaY@XU2Z7U4Fi@/7JfqNhX/rz/B4jNsyTVXTa2alqb7YSJdTaZbUkfUFFeuIVE/C@l50QK447xFaV13U9QQGNCPhhH219CDL4KMFybY4bOY21j8@cq0bnWLjBnnCk3/dRZLW4zJX0zAqQ4bwK0Z2H7u6v9Lxm9HMmjJaoa7d27Wbh7jQymky08i/W1LUGJls1H44osVYzSLzoJhvbBiqPVXg9Zf0WcQr3K@DHkNNxz6o5EX0VMExqk3xAVofJzND1CrQAcd6Psevr/y6A7wtgQ3eLm09TJsIVBLADmjmWHe2DMLBf98FIwj48OB35Hf8R3R2@vyVzgL0dVD6HlZj1Efj2ePooMh6g5V9GoYBfxdf5ca3S2FUOVA4QfOeDKskksIb9jDpWs6Kth@BaydQXZQtF4LyFpYLMvG3ePQQxdS5otpv2/SBWtv0HvmYeWihmcob@eP8DKfCcyfmXjCbMV4GkTeNl@JlveMlScNqnHPKIoFs8qA31ykVf2i9hoHnkrD96Zo98TEg0tiTZ3c85gOLRJDKtOmJXYLz2n1gyCK6eVxC5GAN28SKbCM@JAOCy/6/Y1LhM94eXj6UzBRMgwRQHzEP0WmcQBlRNzAiFNuj7HjqHs1oATOxPp/bRtdcKE@C@r6tjx/7ONZ5trmNvrPppJghWIzieXb2ibGTPjBdXwVhu@P6@UouYITIOQGoceKoB/gC9VB5yUd9ECFGixslD9HxqEK0UG3JQPyw446pnpa/E3HZ3ftPT8kAkxZPf3QH4kqKidEtTM5DR3uC@T93A/DibdxZ3OdGKK3ByRpL@gmSOtVQEb3b1Vi7iw6H6hSbEVn4k1t8tFyLh/dJk9Z0ClJztAXQhvP5YEA3rZJdKAqEyWFWrC2yhz2cP/dx/eO9x@WjUptA8n5EomitbTK5egSxdMhSyFGmIS7r9O5vc5CboXl4l61aAvW9/RqL@kMSwBQt8Y41o6sokvJhPbMwDCs9XCsKqs3kdT7K3ieCrsbsjIZo2dhU1au7PkrKyaKNOa1giKY0OsgjV1QV0/gFww8C0S5YwXUgBjdWmjyoLt/klxz53qlovrUNn2rwMBaqezyXTDzAcyVr4zi0WSYGG2L1HfaRhEGOfRow0Pb9SKNC47ZMM7c4jthsdGF@VwpCK@tiX0hn@EZ9pELiyvuOLg/k@1nTeTOElSIfVJr2rYIKP7v/xTtxjw@ujewIvsCp7gPXem2zeFBfZ@9XFlFttgg2YdOBIbmAxpcIzdqqASdoDdz6Nmw3oMzMCysD/U8RpZ9QSeQuq67Zl9AluMRnhUdwWDoHQOi3cCwfiIMfkAdg45RffFiiK7rbuE@3ftPHr8HTX6EPiDC6OSD5q0b1XKxCNYE7RK66I3beHjw5BBn@7Ht0Kz/LkzXol7GbZWJg4vveLuHuC@bWLQq9kIYOU@9SJQ@vD87bp8@BXXMKrahCpJKVlvfmcOnaPG8nV5HrplsXNCRTl2iOht7/QZvOs9D97V1ajci@HemZ7EBWbj1OqFHkMjFS36pWveHMFu/d/zksVvcaRuI6mb0imKpo4QDBIUExsIgssMTooNP3qFURXy3ggQGPqWiuZssy061vVtszOe5/DwO2j32ylGMBbhnTcpC4sbuYpM2xrEUzEaeiwE8tX1j/9gsQ9rxxLMxkN4hmNGgxQ4DXZkHixuOFDQFzp4hjeuu37xJYZhkErpufXXVxi2cOaDRPU2A5Y41bszHbbdnqYpsj3yHzFtvynmRclJ36tX2MHzjjcNq7XZ9dePO3WCMtn3PC7s3QxhC3DY@@@ZHs5t42Y62fE@DQf9m3x/gotL19VubB/79331/69nth1a38zs1s2y@DOkd3vFIZ2DcfiN26GGMHXdZuoiJIWB229VR@1VQXe@tdjdXN2t3et6dDW9zdW2zu@GtbXW2tra6/fXNTm/rTvvORrdTRdeOlMQ5pw1@k8Ufs@1fLds8xWyzvrrV79dqt@/0Nrb6W/XVtbX1zuZGb3V9vb9Za6@t3e7VNztbneVaW8xPAQZYOe7i3JEegd/JV@4KC2O7SG3/Hw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ]           ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ /                      >/          MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#  ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4ox '6o@]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>  ;
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}  --[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
OOO    program-id.h.procedure
231    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
uuu # >>IF 2>2
ppppppppppppp;ppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
  
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/&&1nu le._e lo=Bid>834757609195 Cry U#age$f =x=>ata?6-/8;fPLesc~+Num;reharepcons>E
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:!*z(\,_)?218:sizeof' '-1?67^*u"":*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0,)[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a )where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint ("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

LMBM code is inside COBOL:

```
OOO
231
uuu
```

Every capital `O` starts IP (marble) going down, if it hits one of `+*/-%#` or `Uu!$` it is a problem. So in most cases marble should be destroyed with `;`.
Marble from `CO` on line 1 is destroyed with second `;` on line 4. Marbles from `O`s on lines 2 and 226 happen to be harmless, they are not destroyed.
All other marbles are destroyed by `;`s below `O`s.

Note: LMBM x position is in characters, not bytes, so eg. first `O` on line 2 is at column 236 (1-based).

Moorhens was changed to use `hi` instead of `dO`. [This is](https://tio.run/##jVFNb9swDL37VxAtBluYo8xG27UBMiBALz1sh10FHbSYjjXIkiApm/brU0lO@gH0sIOoR1LvkSLtvzAZ3Z9OcrbGBZiEn5T8VQ04wjzcNpFswGE4On1J0SVMJ4yDPKAPDamqv8YNHrZgLOrmam1sWM/GuAm1XxtvBxpiuCLUoRgaQr1VMtOu4YABhFKwF17qgwczQr9SGAI6KJobYLUQdQvJTucLhwQopRxW34Bd8rvF7sqjXc3bzBxKbLGPJfOYM5mcqmsTcANhQocg0tEGunfVQWq4tP/yR8ZiC5EGGRQ2JMOjtegKZF/458g6fglxGI2DmHXOgiOoNKJIYLuFnr@I@uPcFNwyTuAaRiVSG7pKXX4/DxL2Zp6FHlKoy@wnvXc4ow7LsvaF/7ouqUOTV1WibXdH4BN8fafXv1G8yYo/jVIJ3xeMf9B5TO5Ddn@YlbFLof5/KnVdVVmXMlBDTX8bqRsWPxhGanuZRQepkSKe/PSC3bT37QPnpDqdngE) a list of two-letter instructions that can be used instead of `dO` – increment in Moorhens 1, harmless in Moorhens 2.

COW was separated from Incident and placed on SNUSP line.

Cubix capsule is now `'4o'6o@`.

Moved V (FMota) to line 10.

### evil

evil broke, and I decided to do something more than blindly fixing it this time. It was hard for me to understand evil blended with alphuck, so I
separated them (+9 bytes). It has additional advantage of making it straightforward to use alternate marking mode to jump to main code.
`j` is rarer than `m`, so it is more convenient to use as a marker. 
The only occurrence of `j` before evil main code was inside Incident, so I replaced `0j` with `0r`.

How evil executes now:

`...  /*"r"{\D-v ef` (line 1) → `mxf` (line 2) → `jzaeeaeueew_uuwq` (line 38, main code).

`q` effectively ends the program because wheel does not have any valid commands.

Comment: "It was hard for me to understand evil blended with alphuck" Sorry about that, I was more concerned with byte count back then :P I agree that it made that section a pain though.

Answer (score 5):

## 239. [Triple Threat](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Triple_Threat), 11430 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNZdhj4mfD@g/1yCbALSACZQOJBggABFouPLvawihyS1dU9JBuVABJEFhOZqMwECRSLHaPxxqzGUnjl8axjJK3VI9nySmtHWLGxG5bDUjhC@upQ@DeU/GVDsaH5B9pzzr35wIvF6hlJuxsCCeR9nHvu69xzzzn3kS3N7f3N3yTww45sc3xp2h7zdNdjHce41h2FPRmzx5rhlgvFWAyhtpzLYV@3PLcaSzCVMUu/YftW2@hAGPPsK90y3uoOxBUYGzj2paP1mdfTPPAYkIrt6Oa7/juPte1@X7M6LkAWGTvSILI7bF8xreV6jtb2DNuCqBJjLyxT67c6GgMI3Rk4ukfoy4xt6P2BN26AZ5WxZ7bj6phjW3ddGyHWohAVgNAcwz7Yev7pFKZ1xj7VoDADUx9NZa/m2UtDdzpTKVSVfX66tzcdWmDfkW2L7WE1pqKK7IXjaqY2jb/Etoaeve9Nh5fZ1qVuaaygrCuF6chV9sTRZpKsMUfXOl3D1BXDajOZ9XRzoDsMQ1jXdqCXPN2s5Cv55laYUmlj2koYOYW27n@Y5ly6EGlf6@DUof8Ght5hXcfuM81ybyAndT0fwiPadWYWi95UWxTykW4pqFFPIeopRj0lph40p0mgUMbQrcP96fBVVjiYDluDErevurN9U6iwY3swng5dZ8@Mg3mEV8yz3b792ti2O1DnqbhodYqFyQHQhv6BocVeu1CUjs5cyxgMdI9HQm/rDkVDwzPTsK5ifLwdOXZn2DasS4DTIbvB0KMudWNtSNZgAzFqFXSwBBEBB4MinNh9PVpEF4YrdJo70NtG12hz2tBHnm650N2uwgxonhvDNFlHNyFBiL2dZa7Nhm4kqGVqPaWtxJC2MBfWvzKZwdqDAeNRUA0o0l6@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@hLFQoQAYOsKmqmLU@9/47c7lJeDZardtpyPI9XMg9jZJAhoVFuZyhgRrW5pJxQK4LObOk0MG15ppdIjFadZYZEGFoFxv7KHZYTRQbwwYcj0NJhoduEPb0zmR20MPyphlfe2Ks0ODUy5UvK@1oGMpA8qbqi2zx9vQS20Y5kQzcn/odStMHuyypJv7KrVZTW0un@tQOEmR0iu53GUNCE5JUxD4kvdRzudbE9Ok62mubXRig7HXs60Ck9ss3q7bA91KJSdwJLNJp5WUFGTTKalm1NtK17A6qeQG0GIDMk5KtXa9fWZUL2pTyaNZApobRIPDVU@1pTiyGhoU17k@yFIKcLLPZeGKxNluE5sco5VIMDbMdNg1D0iQpIZ0aSOBAB9SXFPXB6m8okrIJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICleNi0wykcxEq04YoKYTFcXBemrYyLbMQQ/nc2gUyx0Az3WQdtsaUI@LM5oHEmyWtYiuaRoEzkI88UZPAtduASP16YiGJB9ymF5GRikwhENociTrnchABiYAY9lzZ7ixaaNkRGXCmQdYh4WZapfQNZCYV2SLV4TnRCGTVbqygKEgtpbOKnLLgEGAww14uqD5SN0AvFjgMICND5II7@lrY5zVuFwQDhic0zTWB/bgjFlbR54DzEfnEwpmMqTx54KYz@wuy8uFcnlyjM0MMc/JbcnfAyb9NnfvSMLKRwcTMhrWBa3C1KzLoXYJ/MK2IInWbusDTzAqqInrASuanm8oUBaTp@L2YiuPp/OmScSXjcI8kMnz3hNToYbcRWgpMghkKPZy1Yd1DAfYEszkU7kDwPVU5vFXCDJRgFfxBUXwJQAgMn2kt4cecDUg4Jue0e4BzWLpLM4X@SQ0nT0ERXMHzi53g6yxMGrjUSGm5IIgLMZCFDL26CwemFwRVWMigDo/GnA/Zs3tz0FsB0WEiSASquQ0BWjvAzj7tmXPQQoNGaBFkMkY3g8giZ2gRAwTly920WANxOSgi6DPgGvAyAf663newK3CPGF4vWFLAUrJnTrjfe/QQmLJec7Y8Gzubpl2C9iyC@Mz5@eQaw9bxmiqQhQW9OFrN3YNAljXZXWYud8MgepSya4LDJPCtxE4EhUnxk0o@G8cAAlIgYZKdV1ixXvAVE7GVjsVnyDKeJbFcezGJXBgwqBpPkPhbbKYryFoupQIFi2MkkOonOu0ySFHZFJEj@BUrNjSRNUeWMbYUjwOP13NdHV4WkPTRO/Q4lwuxWUFid3GlpaAtaUoO6M/MI224TV5LHv0SMgUbBn0WxSbuigzSZBmSRgSFGAoACOmHw6tePYJCbspCSqydDeRse44tsPz9XqOfcMoAMFi0UbdtvvI3dlLErhQggaV3rBQPRVzKU2l2lwRIphTSV5OJpXXtmGlbpPLy8vJarIBM@by8ia4NtC1ia4MuDbJJZML4RR0UYosuTD2jFJg2EXy7szHPJIucDiMcLZ/awxS2lm1WrzIameqeBbwKUE7w4wB0DI@AE9SqtfRKUnxxg1UVGl1J2u/jbPeSdsxBqIRPtOuNe4XrVCkZoCOsx1UDGoovNzfJv26A9IFKAPtXspJnp/lzy/Ob887mfO7ZBZTSzWt3oJKQX6pvnLp2EMQQ6SzUlVWLyTprAjCR6uezCfTqVRFBjUONBHpk4qU0Xhrp5I6zIap8/MkNKpon7N2zyF8o2xBkoKmgnKgwAOydiqp3FYg/5Z0IWWSkFZKZkF1qyeT0DJtbASXKo1jaaKBDo@/wxtmO5OJ0fAGrRS/M9MphKHSO5n8aPj2LfIujqMVUJg51LiUNxAAuX3Lh1Uwckpp9aNaXYZ8dCKPT@0u14q28Wf3YC@mj6i3Pj3c2z2uUzY9zb0CmUK@RNgcyMrQKk5HAW5gDjt6bB4MsA1wtcOSoOEAM79st5lsMwKT27wQkemizRZgA15DgqfNZLM/WQW3B@XdnqgDIaFwSnmf/NL2i8TB55YpyHIPOPb2yaRxqn8F8gRruyYK37LDKwDeXJoHdugR6BhVtk86mgUCJtAWyJedwBZg2ZaMvNBX5@xoRtwgAhAUhtIWShLGBAwi7hojUIkTaE8Roj9KrCj9b9sWKKe68pK4YZwBI0dTla7Mlf@PuCCltN1wdIKkD86BqbWB30@iO4@zc0AIHCiXmx8j1WYQTysHpMd/qI4gSrU1C9uvY5CeOjTcHjYv6BI4CzhdaFVUUtG4Q622z9og5V5CS@sjw@NaK4zwE0zyVHNTEupJW1zPQCpDGRkL5ZvtSIC126Dh6yArYyw3l7Bd69pwbAsbWdkF1MCKatgHU8jnNS@Q0dbWfmFncfvOQw4tNhOsRto2inW6cdsujC7LNu1Lm6UBAElTUThh71to3gQtx9MGMKKMt9RAW5e2NZ6iQV0P7MWrxUDf1BAyR/DKa5gF2PxKhwAL6nyy/71dEEPUcj4P5fd9efoElYxgma4jBrZZCCAWPUykG@zJ7@mD3njC7Iv0we0mHhkPaWByS5YGIiSUSozwt5Q0Osh5CIxzP6rju@bVfZd0AjTeRfXqidpPSCt82EANE1PBGOo3xQTSmQ4P@xcZ13lugm8FpgK527c9Lfe5Aiwaf2IoIcsGi7u55HIyJ8v4G6coVmiwXEe/ziGXCjGPdvX2XNwjXW/nMBYnN@Y75jaPH7mgac7hY9EPVJM//TYIUk7X/zKTQcZOpQvy5oWGSf60N9Rjertns/g5qBjRmsVhguiBrixDy4MAiHpJkEwsgMU8ewhqXUc3jb7h7ZPB3rRQd1GIeSvItUQsLjWECI4MHQRybnAIJxk0qodzlHXJ4Y@BkxNWUPEV3qSO3smlQ2zPbNsBvdJlKtkUCkHT90VEznYHHcUbAQKeapfmd9ef558f7uw2j7ZOn9ZzQ9fJmUYLeERHb/ZBmTVhOCz4YNnQQrgLtGNYdt@AGvko316Zx7btceEBVw0e9klgQh/HwU7zYP/J8dbxl6JwNKMb/aGpYRmrK1MAAY4TgrkXTdtu2SBbWMOFmEC4OHxyeOBj@ezFwf5Wc2f36PA0gub10DQ0dZQbXF0uqtBnCMJUJc@b/tDsTC7nkJo6YUUQzAZ1rhoD3ZTJMvzKGMYzRa1MwQgUkXF6lGW0Amto53ZYQc2vr3daWqWir3bapdJaV@t2OqWCWil3K@VCOQ8/a6vrOntH4LKsj8hyAy5uFUEDEuYBhaeHqpR8CQdU0TZILOO55Qpi7ylcu1zW10rr2np7fX1dK6x1ilqhsqbrq2vdUj6vr6r5bquiVor3Fi5SDBStQl@fLEAw6tBYQJHA/FLwmBgOvPAg692wTqFQWG2Xu@vFQqecL3Va6/lypdNS17TWup7vlopqQe20C2rVT4sWVeASPegwlCotEE39KFmFSCnmT6bRLqYVVn/VXTCclSKymIG/ao6Kg4goYcRQrJmjaVaEr2J4HxfJQ4mVvEGgAKwQIK6VK07LD1zHwGCVfGL9GFii4JPz4hcnEphv1fwdIr/BdfZIPW5VlcKvvW53IrhAwVcyTllmGFykYL7KPrm@LSo7EzUXOMBXInx8dX4uvpmoucABvjLHh6v689FNxcwDDZCtEjLcBTAX11TEHMAA0xphiu4cCOMqFLdo24DIa270wkQB7nXCjdsDQlS0WUAE@YAF3g@q2dSa/b4RAvshkShQs2DiU1fDxOUgsT2V1DbC4ACcN2vBbIJ6MYyMEz8kGhUk4i3oby6I0mSBN6BjD8aRoXRb4HXvG2KMRoi7yMcCLZejkuFMRHLK59sImq/5Sk5T7CLAkc6ZxylIqQc26BYHBq5pdCe4SSywTpzH4r6JZdLIFsYUwiUkJl/PX/uKRxFxRmlYVzYZFQJXM6@oZcQSoOhfmbMpu6CG0c8E6EyhZmP43N5vdelnDgAKJNNWS4ogk7AQi0AM0XLH9EDj8LwSTJq5J7Jv6d0haIi5lmGh@wNg8nqFILutlrEIFFoCd2X4zzlgVXY8BC29oJQU1TcJ4LISzGfcRn26f0iALY0U3Mm1ETbR@N7Q8SCVeP6X73egE2a7qKeNSU8OHE1LvyH66C7sMZEUPfQzv3dDiYgahlwfQtnWcDlaMwPHfNTU@7Lc05w@qqOiu4FA8Qco4R5a4yXndir/OT@TKqNGnlyDYZbRZ@050AQ7tVzEMyMDhGlrHWoGbiYwdErkYGfzbtBHXGGOCIPAYhZlNGdVh4XbKLze0BvyX9w58aFuNAb4vW@ICsh8WWupOqgPWsvQ7@l0R7sadmwZpGCqMhZsdQ5sWHsyZMpdU7viziY651efV9AxLi9B1hLPRWA3PdD7SGHP3dDjQ3ThWkN3ILegszwYOOSjodC/JwfH5L@LQAyxlTJwLG41w6SfB3R6QFxELiDuUkPjXi850mjGVDObWmuMZozex1MZZkhCIfCcejuTyRdxGg3WxaPbtBanx7mX0q@vz0/Nd5nxJpmneub47jKZG9epzmK/2Qc6FiYuo6@ZcqETcS7k6L5ZPXTNASWbltw2NRdIyxPdoV9D99HPfeSOM1MbVFIndN1D7GFx/O0Ri1baBdsSo7ptm4aLQ9tcxEGnFyfDPHGfH/1EzPXGvIbtkJzp9uTANZ8v2G0Pl7kXENoDuBxfYcY1/AjlKPaiRmvbN/hdKFr07Gud/86f6N7OLdUDOJZsEkkY7bkzSqf9IUrFrVL0M78dr@aWy2ubc8Mnx4Bv/okqrw@ka9cwbZed0O99zQKytOvy3/kUHW1BQ7NkWiuLuucnE4UaMEVYoBf0q2Ze2uZq5TKnwc/Czh86XZwTxPOh3C/gXqr6Ye7ly0e2pYrnQrZ/lXOuPtR3tGzj4IaGiPOeGXgeCxMLtosrCJoE7lKaX7m9fIVSKjluY1jUAU67d6ON/ee3mFkWta4/swzGJG@D@IcJ1ivg8Bwug3@b3Er359Z5GHuaQbv2oUpEOvfK1GEio9@ZLmWFvPqRKdR8/uHMqmsO9aE@l1cdtl7ruLf@Hi3k4YXKi2qsCEswWsvQDhxAvRX644NKjXM4@u5lMJppwCD/oKQzl98NQEYfoMp9BI4jdMwmvLSGg4nOndDirOP7W6438Ee23ZkoJMZ8LEeqfFiemhDkXZ2@9ypXXBnEdb96MZ/PC/kmYtuf8NyndBWDtK8N/juRMYWEOU@YSubgDM3K0NXGlSujgfdh3KiwyAJAwOvrOcuwdG@Mv4u6YB53bdm2@TFdBky2Y6C8BlIoLoJ9qOtmZCGxM46Ftg4XLSWt7iIrB5@AhDYKrYeK9n29HzVDP6hbZVy@h1F5OeW93@4TMWp/KBeY1smYxLeRmIsFTWFBUZWKsnbvCOTiq93STY0/Rqul@/CtK8V78QUiipCLaZ0P1wb5amC4upyY4lODMTSW0QGlpqf3dfLeow1onddD138sBBrZ@J0TrdDa66J0AwMYg4W/EyuPEdHJsy1QwzzNudRRjzFxh4AIXcSM/ZWHuY2739cudX6@7j5uGZo2cBs11/5C53wjR5XvwGtDMr4N5n5SgMF0pY9d/zkX4bNxG/pz2P@waW5q3Ldp09aHBrqSm7vg8gHZ0OrZPaun9/iuqMC3aHgARXr8ZOR9lYDyix1XjHhUdNdWtHVN2zQf0rrIIznHtO3u3HLt4qG1DiT9KLxjrQUR4vFBsx/M79RINNEvGjs9fQjTlGt79kCXybcI1EQDEf9dxEn9RbBva3m61yoALeI/vy3@D@qjl5rtDQb0aA7MoUs/lFSms4bzunKPsnkIVRge34bFaVe/tFvtnvGhIrV0zbOMq5xvBeLee7XZQaQVDCbvYLBiGtB4zlhBaqhH40/wsb@oSyPLPHNrvz10nDHW3bNt5pr2TcgVJneQBMZavsaAjkV5ijXTOdEkA@DeQn8P3T0LHWKJdSFJkaiNYrWs50FMURfajSY2uArWRWt9C6SgqXpTYSLrax9j8BQbPsj0Z0TsshA@QSkTy/BzpyarN7x0ZxkbN8d3QKDCn7k9vHWJZ4inOph3Jsw3miUec6ffYOXxvgWT8r0rJkpOrHfK@nCh/cs0Bi7/ZXK3MBfL7Pr5LNR4vv4ruqKjd/miBro@JML1bQdPSoGsILcd3W2jTRzZLBeMOEux7Etgt7LJQmAfdm4VZpfs5/d0dCqTv3iuX2q4j/TAwC2l5hwiAMzTq/cPQfzdoeYa3x3anj4X5/Qq/kNQPtMujfbTiV7wEfqtKzYd8scEtWPQbEfc9AyXDqz4jvkjhJMZrcjP0cKmzO7Bye/7zSMRAUjsb2fyPvP3wQcONPxjvDY3r0nxUizGL2RqhkcmVfGcW8/5Ox7usy3cDPuDoSse83OnzUdR23L/isLdGwM4nvwGGCzraaY33/4cMamC4CRmutC5SJz@nmHal@x7lTwDOQtmXpSuFxDWE5h3jzQPRoA1h1gp/weucqLFQnZ45d4AIehFJhuW4d1vnfE8DRQe/4kV4jIVHq/MHeCv8vhjMcin81vl4F5RBKbscdvE0/4fK9ZzVjsY507oND46gwsBosQustG3BUJ/8rD0m6jyde@KTRVnTNsaejIeX7hv9li9d/aoslFlNUIeLPXd3WcvJJ9KLnttvq/3QwKlDlrd0DXHoWvhroE5xGdYIHkt5r@zKXz1YEenOxuOaSfqA9JtDfCIGLH7HXueGnM0htnno3QhmECG/R29jcuIDyrDc/sZSGkwpQ2A4faPddwDMMVjFifGpAd2WzOhzToPyu6E0M@ZL0ItWhvoLeh7M3TNF8MWId/RPG2B6ERWQVL1AtcHackwW7rzGm1@UfciDXa2UE/1EekciwmKj1TZa7e5rI12uIlxFFHDq@xkYPOj4/fQRMCGYPKgn4cvpCu4ZXtiMpyrh83W8/Ca7yTRO/y84qKKOnrLNvkvzjQLmIVl8H0DmmPobu7AsIYjCmMySHPzdRu@ezmvrKFFw@3BELwxQJUONjXjPjS@Q9oN1QWxs8e61lxazZ@vyExsoH74hqGe5rRtXBYTjo9cFIuchPsAlw92iPNdBy0goBGwO6099K9T@EBRzX6rTz@LFZLJ3j7WW3jasEVHZz1tNE@knDw1JwKnzq35jA6H/ypLHYHaI314qpvW2SZb3RjQD7H8m7mk4mf33NDbbzXpAzOwRibjDwCdguhj6uy0hxsm74MVRyXoVpfg/L@bFYd4IMxwxEFhV/GvKErQgSfqSH/rPUvgHQVDVDg921EYwaVSWiYjSTGeCJf6Ly0A86HojhW8f4Ff3@IymNI9gjW67OyMrdyOqvmqesfqLF6Ns4sLjhU/dBvA7mhAF6Qc8@RnK9pFfSUpy8mV5LlVZflkAK6bIM7OBdcmYLsGPXh5wybglyfZdPNRUOMav18CCAjvbulpVgfa@4VF6zEgfzj8lgR@Bccp7iv88z/oiCtt6OqmvgEqJTQIXkll9/WefbPJ8xW5w2ys4ZU4iAO0D5Nf0CBvbzEQi712j99kY9@wF3unFXE/hrj/CjxH3G4QlIJ3Li5V4Fk/j3ceL01wbktkHKTyKwWy1rBvAfvqeD1XYScGHeMbOuHGfHEpmuU5aIvsZNk@6@i4hYtOZ5L53bTtKzqxgSX58z/gt4LQGU1xds7Pnm4DiuSIRzFVuoqj3baHUGofyVvdsQVIChsZdJEhLnbRZVQULuHJRbquBChS9i/roGz4jR3bWydM3mVJvOYKD9fXjG5qZev408/P8hf1r1k/p/@X7@ekW9Fw8U/k9VU3nmU@SO0OCSsaXYboMDbJ4iujOM8wOMBqiOF4w/sDr@jiRIZnWH0as@2BGDV04RLdLxRQozi3n0I39bN/a0ef7moigtVv6NYOOillofxEd4W5MMDAKxFqPurqK6khX3@RTzxWhgzx5hMNXPx2JzrSiTdQYJKVEXvHekhkMAur5Tz4eEOaeOlJv/7E3@BbjG68zu3orSFtPrwuKIVynaqz0qxvNMgFE7yNlw@dfXU@KuTl89Ha7kXO9Rv1/Hz0Sb7wBbS67UCqRzkcebvPd25XlEb@3TtXG7N4/C5Z4xvFgU2s3B7tH@2enG6dvjiBXrjz2c8eP0rj8xqkIjod17NNutYJ2gUn94/gP4EPL1lIsRWNbeCliZIUi55jIlDR1nE5vsKdEdY0kfoDyeeld/VI/CyA4Gldg/kUtQ/TAPYhEBu2GlZ@OMDLqZhIKy7YISozkMfjAAoaBrfjz@Gl1FRxVofGkqGxHthUbHFlN3nYQ1rsg1jub7bNuSDYYkF@Z0E8r@LcJrj7pdR7ABPlL15vjuX@ehPMPfUG0CDUT7O3tX/w4nh3MhnQGD2J69bXy@IAH2fOONL4rg3/RiE6Ny8S4tpVPc7ilIB7xWTG7zXUvRsdqiWYY7vPExOFUvnjsZAwoWXqeK3oRY23RSpFJUAZpIbVmjpf2DVGkSL6c3QE3S2vYsAE9uIBar/gSlxgTtD9kAp@/GogVtFc/tA7IiYu@HXSjYo/WX/EYdVwjh66fMwtmKqCWcdl8B@ZlXxX4YKNmJjO1AsmswJ8Td26hAr7sFKNz1FshTdEfIWXPR6UF6/2gzJ1XmtkWaa94eJcHszSpjbAe8QE9HPb06vszdCms/8@MwnkC7pVUuPXcFLX8vsl6U4BENpBOvXnLcK3v3dSR@mMi2bE36M0N7RwogIgfimmOJ3rOXhlKT82yW@n401ui4vQ/KmSdDFXXHwUSAkuuzZcA7QI6oQuyjgmcEqsjag4XipLtz6wLdMFmaQD0zdIKB5OtSCcKHRgiZ9aki0WTwBNKoHImGXxGMK69dmLsWAqvQE9qf2KJ14hOMLsRnAmN5ZlGVruEpRHcfipineqkgpSZZ4zxP1IjeRMEr8IVXLJPa9vRgDnXBF4rufe/8Zv82sBzz1w/0i4R/kn4Ps14euC@9f9GFUF3z8LfAXw/Zj7vsphl83ehSayFxaOhae7gC4fx2fqhDzBv0eW6hL0Nvb05/tHzG3jDaXYl33QCcNuQg6DNAd6PNBfH4jimvoYwXkOYReGeFJnnwOJAF0BfaB4gxIN5ac7Fym8Eauay2HB0fas0J4wfcTXbOmCrDdDvBgShLDcanm1pOagkPK1j5Du7LjEIyocoSRVgSfGro1B/RXozxsbGyzutjVTr6/WOG3kVrSvivFXQUFXADbGFYUzBmkgSZgC4hoiWWpFy6gSJsWJLKkmkad1bE5qIA2myAEgEgZb/il/EDdt0VRAx5Y@8khiGvsKEDBsy47cCOsjkgERx43XF04Px/DYCZpDIgNUiXZD/CWCnSBYNT6PWM@@YufeuXUhrrFkQHg/m0O6Frj/yZy7LTll4S0ms5cqpqavRMTasMcnlo1WpT0oLUsVcoViTl2VIhQaF6igvDjU3wFKGNzALNq68doeuFvbu/ufHR6dzFyuQ5DJabAkSzY2Mueykj27CBzJoNyTjfpkL3fy7Mme35TRUoV2HYQI9@RNF3NebtMlXZD7S37CZzZvipjJSM0/FDFtdpH3aC/rLPYwNhcB3OYHDGZyTUm3d2cXG41zKzGT/bt5F6YmlDQSF7jOXbouNTldTCxicBf8Kd4F7yr@8VUVz67ioSbPvgpP1oqASAQH97EAB4gpOR9qDsX6BTjk9pnwOosCv4zeJdbHbTh0jWVQogjkqX9tPQ6t8PY1ce1YT3N7ptGKwdzdwav4@KUh/q0YwXUjijswDS8lxcj6UUcJCJhYSlxeP6qOFFqsStGlqYQry@67yczHJ8VgEAC@5NHQ7bEje8BC09OO7ruOQRBhO0O@eqGzz4Z9gOvS41hHFquDaCJDYmioZFBUrlDDyBIXmY0yeFkc5HeG15mJiiv9Tjk1kpSePuoYl8DAU1IWRvonKkhUwXFirDRdbmYlgcfxFv4UD3ZEm/Sj7rMbhci1M00xrI4@SuEFLdULEE0xPHnz8jopxWdogC7V2/av4Zq6Xc8fiJonRkR4M93UYFtfDwbZ5PWH6@t4yQ2ejIZugRxPPOcAnDA/pbp9bcBSQ7r20WUKI2/qPGVlXc@RmNzgN0dYLJMhhRoeFAECM4J2yUWEw1J4S3IqV4fewVDX6uDjrTFgZ6qiXICbMpHYChrTtmEqRzOUFAMFCZJUCW0d@5ZVsUScehVOeZAG42N0DxXDuw/nRNNthbjAB@MU2oJqzRqPIvf3hCOQt@r6elX0xiSrWWdAFrNcXskB2jksxBdQoX3FQVdoNbzNG699d/SOAWzh8Xd0y9KhgYBm@hrMwdoQiMyRsv7bKrLh7c@UQ4IX8ak4OQsFnbwVejd5a@K62UquRnaZ2h3Mqa/OcVLtiml1nPvvc0qudptaMevjHAg6UiO10qurmWI6k1mx0qkVC6f6R4/QnHO3ApJEUwHtaARA8oop1YCeQfKor1i1FW0jtdKpF9KUArygn91Cgq/dnHK7ot3lVh7BTJ2FEIcP3tSKSxcL5hVFvYPy4QhZyWWBZm7xHjZ6bwVmv2JkMlgGZaWJBfg6d36SIZ59fpIjy1FNCKK5y74YblNcNeiJmRd18AYUwaKjgbEXkLGLDcxNHzi8E7o4L26B7MEz/g6eCWG0QU13o5J/fDLm4YxF8Lsk3fnEr3HkNztCA45S0IjozWqSBMzkb/4moa6yeGplc7VoZ5LlfA1@1FqZldknK@eFUoIlHoOmnkvHnfjt@U7lmundwuobWT7Tusqbi6Oro6MvpPNUMrF9@FVcLQHoGlun70M/a6yw4MM@7pNIpHOxRC6tPlrL5V69egXiLnzOGkojCqVcSGdy8uIstQaextpaOrtaSWcfJ5tUFClVKEgnzDBy7NwYuJ0OfO0evTAmleAftrmJeYED/pkI64@6PCwsDAcRoX5aP@oDcNVrrZxg52uals6UCo@tmlLIF/78j5fvsrdHzY0//5V@Tl/GxyE@fnT3DN0navmT5eVPnjwplbLQeNx99L2jL7e2tko72fLRWXmzJOeXN/7sT5eXC4WNQm75wnXVi@TZ1RfxQr4UV/7895JHR99tui72H36KTAUn/lbgq7JymV2xt/C56jL8J/fbTsStobvVfYsTJAjLdWI2yWS5mDz5KonVfZtQVTUxpr8mNcMyUxuba//1J4dvEl6iUci9dODpJd4kVisJ7gQH@Iq@7zrRSGwg2OpdYpyr1@vgXPuv/x7SNz4DPBgz3oCfRtnHtTpONOQ6JXmXaKyCQy0UIN//6/vfjyUaIySExv4eKzQKaU4rauWR@ijoo/OEWikdPoZg/0PBI/9Diq6qFs79/ox0N3ZtENyDykO/MjsSFvS7TxkJJqiBHA@Fg3IndvHzF//HX/z0L35Cfz@l73/Cd7OsLj9@tcOYDjMwfqrVx0HtcmytErdtGOU18B0E4ceKDB@l6ftr6JVFzRKVerbJSxWQcCLimGqH4JeJJgn8HwkXS/jryfIZu4h0QbyB/Mkv6zOLPeMfy4J/@PpeDMEAcFksLLTftomwSYPM2XSY3xmBh/m8gH0MXCzxNTT@aM6HNcJwRlXgpSbHs0jNwrohOWzCZxn@6B8@gRd/lylEBBPI7GeZfftPLHGWOLu4eGrhX@sN/h28xb83Hv6dtvHv@A3@nb7Fv2MP/45c/HvWwr8oL48lZOAMmcwxiIyCaB/yeQFfRWkKX0C8iVjil/phMZa4hc9FRr67O1O@ytRq4h8kqVrgww93QZku7mR546tGJnNGZTtriEJuyBcNxotMv0rzqw3Am9k426jb2/RVmg34yBdfNc42JhOL9I8fZ3C0PgYEjZULBsJ7o8HuNu4ad2cbd3cbG/C/Qb93/Jks2clV@zE4IXbmnx7hp7YAKPjcXSADPT/LNc5z5w3@uQC/kmtgiJI7B0cDnk0APDuLJW6RXNjZBV23VJfP1NXyhcxoSKSrGNd2Gauq6UIxVx59srpbiCUK8XgujVHvcGIC8WI9lkAhfZ3L6usU8Or9N/8bfs/ff/NvwQtFw9edYWwsUWcMhJyVzbyZv86rV@oVOAyWBxmzl@@pHWTqeZ3lx/kxy/dttQMuHf7y4DLyXZa/ZHkrb6kqRILDY3kPXV14XMJfF7A48Gfk84g8f80gFxOnCrqKlZ7vmkw6j52x@CsdpBNFTSr5pLKaTBoX5dXBm3g22Tw/S17UEjn3/DzH5TZWKNXoDt67O9Zs7j7faTZzSMrnz@zD8P/wsB/13vvfP7SfHdp9G/4PDw@fQcdlHmfkx/CpNzIb4rGZaNQ2z6sy0qNPmYncxuZ5oyijezUDxFbAsMxHfkKM8Gwsn8dAqX358qb28iX@31zXbmrkCLzgaNYCAAHGHRDIAwDBy1qNHOiGzzVhJR86b16eBy7uyL28gaCXDMTs4D834fsl/Bv/7/p/9oKlzi4kGAe3dxsp@kj4J0m3d7d34rchpVLCk9qAPwwAPya5vWugk4BuwXWWki6kuzseBr8paYMjbGAeGw1KHALCoE/wXM@TIGmAYpgSC1rn56N8Xqq1ICQwbWvvaG1EqtGukZUWrmeBMqSmJQIpl2q1knCvVWq1inCrq6u1WjqAyoNHOAFId7V2DUdTLTGQsAx8jKXyaDOje@6T8Wr80aOUeDPC5mAA2q26nn/3LghqNjuG02xiePHdu3gzjvtG6utl8Ocr797BOE9KoPc@t8WK5TposWquEObQ01zN85zUW2OQjeOOTDcu0U20@TyCYmpW3thYLTUaqyVwr1YkqRZf4VtOUpeZdVW6W8nFeT1AH00mRJRaWZMo9C6J8SyxwTYbQO8uftjtXYKam5XKUqo11qVbCPHD1PV1HshKq6lKZl381Zcl1kgz8Xd2dlbMlNJr6ccXFxdTAgvypNqtVlfv6rdaFY0ld7W2uNQc99xrjx4V16F1KvnaeazZ3Nk63Wri@9BwFRhmAoaBxN1iuMI3cJJnZNkqr1@cYY0uzpPJau0x7@FKmSWSNQEnJ4FRsso6VTwB6rPRxcM2I8I69U0nBkxdK8IUExvQbpy1POvggqbD7G53GQKhb1gL155d3TT9W@BvbMfs3BgdfTmWODrY2t49zRY2YLYq7G1tZwsnL54kVPSWQz9FF9F/vLu1c/gCEhwd7G6d7H66//nuiyMId2Ov32q6rulDXb9pDoc3b/CicL2pDyA0/DT1tuFqr19rA/qwGudrNzfvf/bD9z/7H97/7o/f/@4P3//uT3/@zU9/CN8/gO@P@fPH/269jL8//@af/f773/ldCPxP8P2P8P3jn3/zm9/nX/L/CXz/cyTsT8Q3Ase/rJpopPEDhFApVDJpmDjS6@tADBS6EYO8fu3n3/zk937@za//Fnz/pfj@1uz3N/54/venP1j8xXQ/@f37YX787@H7hxyXD/vj3@Fh@JyB/x0O9@u/9f5f/O/8/8/EHzp/9/2/@BP8EZ5/@lt/9p/f/8r/WShU/uzfvP/hj9//4Cfvf/Ar73/wo/c/@MeF97/5b9R89Of33//0j/7bf/jD//Yf/if6/wP6/cOH/L//rX8K5PpXf/Qz/P/JH/3Vf/wZ/v@v/@qv/uh//qtf@9fk@G3u@L//5b/jv3/5Kz/8yx/887/8lW8W/P7w3t9vHhD@zd9CyMPL@RA8D6nXx4Z8863K84u0RpgL0ADdzM4KIAM@GeugncfyLC9@YLD99J@8/81fBRr@FwAJvv8RfPDPPRD1I/J88cVEXIZ0eDnzxRegFH0hlKMvokA/YuxdDuTV/ON3APAFxfIPC6Ag0/8FoQCMCSgfbCJzAsEdgzz459/889/D8CAlhv5qFF/eD43AriDwO7@KP8JBG1QjCvsjHPbvf/b997/3j9//7Lff/@zXkOfLpfXsVlZWP2A4BMDyA@AQcPUhcACoomIEGuxyrACO5Q00dMXUzKtX0AnL4AJ1JB0rF8EXUxvkVtENCUHfTXP7UgYtS/AdxUrr4EOLUwYm2wyPykDUkwy@gTgTG9UhjkDx1cUMnY0KmhBQda4DXkzE02SbFRDx2egJYYGU9cwxa6brI54wgwENwsCwQBh0HFcL8UylvgMZ1kc7DHEh8kzsFTxf1RuV@qiB6L6mIgCOzBPIEqDwzciZUeNr8NcJJ8DHRjtfQ1Eq9UymUYGQOlWVcss2KU@1TJWjumcY1RvDGcNde5uPGfskrlbiXLeHpmQCGn8zIfQmmbg2If48kxbVoX/fSd80pod@GlH78DAev4nBlF4AAF5Zxs1e8JVlLM1jiB5xVBnKFh4ZjgFaLiOMg0EACSKZWIb6N0MeyB/K8DGfDT4JIzqszsrKCrg2GvFivHkImhVzrqqupzm4HkVyYZXFV9fjGIybZ/iOwJUjUsDSO2n4VeF/d5l2wVJNaunYShIV8yTzc5IzRbtkJ3gl/BqSL00VyBAg@wRi8Pv4MbihhegZhsUSYTou@tPSI8jsJSbFUvSqGYm0fx2FHRZ75l4@sUcgn2fj8ay6iksKErcNxL60q9X612ppLQZP8g/xJTfidSvQWfiqX2VjAxu9cSuTmQKdIACuxhoNsXbK1FjjZPcUwE8PmVrIKwyk@dvSWqFULpULxdXV8lpBLa2ul1bLlSKwstV8uVBQ10ul9cr62h3V5TFwg2w13SpvNP7RzOe/@0fzPvND8RNrfMFGCtla72INs8637q3gGmr8PB@vkbmEWm7lLJ/Fv0KxCL9QxqxaXrtYXjZvZazyOe0Xu8VVaihm7FYeoW13CT4sthRjSxAGH8gEl5GYWPjfP6yJRV58UR1f6I2rZSAeKXYOxMPRQS/e3t5GvrHE8ve@57FGAwR4eX8vlgCi7zF/VVM2OkpPodfLdYaOTrGXjO3sf75/sn/4XNnZPwGh@ktWKOaVWOLu7q4b2OLJq7PDw0NKBSpSUUXXXZsNh0OKbYH/bqTF1IJcKMoF@FXl0F2U1aJc9EOKRXkWDGPz9yV5eGAUIc/i2@H52BzDfLkjPwEzv4Q@5BwM3C2SxFhsEP3U4BvDUfsIZqRHKneWV0NnHp0b4tBxI0YrnGcwYi5i@Oqls4vYRi6IPMUz4M@B8mCsWuwA9/h6Nju1@V7SJ3p7AcR2j79EfNuxQeH79jBPNOuKR@0Y/NBpEPVUw2sk3b7h9RZAvBj08WyV7vytYdjtt6CAuNbBAZ7Aj2Pa9jyANfbiaEEtnwV3ReBmArosAsCP9z99ehp5nu5ubT@NrbInh893ph5lAVRmB7t7p4F3jcf6ScsBii93Dw6mveIBE0CNNPxlVl7LZmEehR98ZulDT2XlKx9EVe55981KrlGpOfqjR2pd/Vre8FbYi/qTrzPPh/1KcV1dLwMBQK0vdWto2kYH6p7QPO3IWXHZ0QGaJtDAUG9o5u0dK62ZutL8/OyiBpLRkBUbsWe4qXFd5YdzDDf21L5hfXx/Eb6rzIvhAdUOvqMYrTwtfFnwcMAWBsIDg9DpGJc9mPJubB8g1tI0Bt@P/UD6qKEA2uveAI/nQWEzMeYccFxJN7osH1PICl1Yr5Qr68VCJVtZr5TK6mq5nFULWXWtsrYO009erairlfK6mq2U1oslmB8htry@FkvAtGF0czmY@9V4HJ5VQGu18Vr5Dbyf31Z6jViC29bY25QmsYQW@IcsrkOaOL78yfVoy3baqMcLJTxPUVQZYNRYmyX29rbze3vx@BP0oLV9Ox@Pd9BTruTza0/icZ1itmEOL8TjNk8DUQDmcU8@/2Q7Hh9yBHjXRTzeQ8/uKiol8biBnu2tvT3M5zV6CpgewK54DPeYvmcNwCz0FIuk1cTjbwJ0ALfFMypRSXfRg3lizB6P2Ya4ePxTvzz5PGA45nAcw1O/rltb8fg@92xtYcxnVPEyL@p30LNFn3jcAQ8QYTx@CY5LR9eteLwFTiTFeLwNrvZYgzC8wh/vPrA8LR4f8wbCJorHRwStta/iIH2LcMzm6dOnWs/r6Jf8M3b4sw1FgxhjNNzda336aevysuWMt3Y/PcaYzz57qr0eD53WZUskazXhY0MaiLnqj6c/UMb9ZlMz58Z8B2KsqZjmuKlj2ZraGyiT@FxiJv3mZxDzGcTMW33l2ODTB9AWfp704flEa1GM/6EYeo5arXgNCdUbD3Q0P@KYoZeYZ/ta27Fr6B/Vl5OpZHZ8tpq/qFEw66ek23ztDmO7KXqBHrJE6XZ8NqrnL0AjWyuIMx@p@PmoUDbi2eX@JvC26rK2qRZKmVEVbyC1u0mWlNXNlPoo/Tb1XNosFEvV@Pnmphw/Uy82C2qlurr2VXoYj0tV/N0srlXfpvLJPGP4I52tXWyulSMp1tYyWq5QXVuTanfQEh7MS62hpzebqdSNrl1JEpYVRUUoP39X@5iqaNS6qVF2VOeFYmOpNqqrwKO9IcxH@RlcHbzqYYhvqeIYLwHdaDNfRc6ciqvrlTjkn8tJyIuQe8Dz1Ut/XSd4RBwTTv5RWFXmL7hTK6uSggcImna3SS//Ya@ikKghxF7iQR865OtvyiNdyq3GTlGhQPavMbxkpoXv1KRz1aDP8gtLGDfXqGvrsVhDiNRH/BUaNeHFiyGUPXx5su0o@NJPbyKGX1vgB7GTMUgHfWX/UHlhuVo3wHKqjzzlqY677tp@2DY/iavsjvCt8YZt1W7ll/IdHf/Gs7t4TwbMglq9AS6tw1KUO9OkG6pXs9GoN@t9vT/wxqC4UVs0gsQwp7InjEPiMSD/JESz/gSqm69ZeGOUjt6VUWIUa3Tw/osn9Se3w2oVYO9qep1eCx1P4NGpTas@pPoc6Q6e2tk/XOkyHY/HtHuvzncRcBua9vZObjjMqgWl2Hd5@wQHMahAt1ggEdGs5@9ql/UzDH@HPxtyPH4hy2fvLmINGFK1cUKru8MWf0lavgUa32ptBGHqWqnWY61666tRzakPQE9hNRMaK6J/Ma1G8O9MmB2bSrM@CqtdrJ8VigXcdJUt5NezBRWmRJgqARq@a@AvwVeFL8SrqKWlzFScsXg2P8oralbV1axn71rQyvlqFRsbuom88NSkTCFtpjo20zZk6jQYoTUqopbtsYGR7aUg1bGumRxcklPym83VTKkkSbU3UDpnJdVRnkibpVon9YQ1JQiAiR2@BbZaqnXrqa@kWmpZqrv6m1q0y1NSrIGDnGo8WIbGFaqnO@yf5dnyqpq9lZvynam53oq6VqieDVfOZBWql393uRH/XiN@AW1/x0CHYNG1IBAaahDmD2kuZoSCQhg2QFnR1KGr1PVCTYDEBoK9pOIpfEsu39SZSibXCsmklKyhkWMZwgV7Il6SBMaWfKRuxkFQiVfj6wXQaCNsaaYIfFlwFZTNu1jHcAestB5L3Mbubu82olsJv8PGYy0j@95HjF1mVmIsR2vcSjPBlsklKw2yRG3Vty6Pt2oCems7lqjS7qtwBw07Fwdg5dzyxy6sZzYaX/HnOe4NgVxjdMPJGbsQOwkKRahzJ@KH@rm3Md6qfK9EbiPTyJ3H4nEaqXxZsVKWeEnZ1wm6B5xt3/rvf68@Q3sBS2lVPgLPLqSvnxvmbaUoN0j1S7HE1xloEdxI1sh9nQCGfkcNLXZx3d4Obm9Bj7/DQ92FYjmWsGx/gxcolB5wOpgJyuU42n10NjhZ/2rtq8pXz14cvjjcY4/z1Uq1ElULzh9ns2pSTW6wxyCAGse7oHK8Y3ZZ/dr6jPawJWqJ6iBZLCWLE8nqiVG95C8Ip9RGQ1Y3CmwTaJVVgd901VU5/67BCa9BEasFiHn/q79VGm1UwF8AIa8KbVrOFBoNNV2QEoP33/xbPCx1u/v51gFLYgX/@k9/r7D213/6r2ixMnlX45VeSwAkOtXVtcRFghehtMYk8NCKZ0FNNHIiXF1TpYQrcx8Ur5xw34lrK1KFfAXitg@5L74KrZZYT8QSlWev3jG2Abpfo3N5aRTIlctN6FMrVdCh4J99jbayr@XlV8BLXHclB@nZOgL79p10o9FIoyWcJRsZPN9XKNO6wtld7YIbCVCDSFv0p7tp/NO/CgLSrgt@3wfe9IbOyg2VgcqRy73/1d8sFFb/@k9/41x613zX/C6w1PX19VW1kPib2U8uvRRj6aUtluS3a/IZGy/WDs4@Jifesou2yvSSvHNyuP2d3VOcsnULL5Bh24fPFYw6Gejt8PBq29Q1xxzzM6PdMULhTH@6fcRsh73YOaI0L@nYMoWSzVHksrLfqYqX@2WvmaoUcYG/nMuXcmqZgUSWX6sWVpkG7M3Fa0qEawWTMqrWtj0Yc3UxtS1R4qUthMG4AwPUeFevsk@PDigFcY/00s7us0N2@PzgS8UP5eGnT/dP2Mnh3unLreNdqMez3RMW3zph@ydx9nL/9Onhi1O29fxLBtHHW89P93dPEEEuhpwR5VneYIHqxjbcsZtDYdcl/W0i2LXbV7o3Ga45Ay2Ht8dPBlv48jkdX9M0GT60DFAOo6rhydYSlxUZotc6HSeG56WNNltCtXApDfIFHtfu5d01Vh5@8TbvlJdZu/Q8ucba@edWcWONmXnxx8xSv3jMlpeXz614MK9EqxFoptEgPBoEYWGZ9r@3u5RaLbE06KOFkhTGPD88Wsr7vqWXx6dLahB3vLNUCDz7e0vFwLMLvlLg23u5s1QOfE@2vrO0GiZ7vr20Fvh2dreXKoEPiHRpPcT5fGdJzcf8xroGGXCJXrec2ts/2GVpAJJqE7Fo@kXHVDA0RAqkNn55DTY5S6dvenaWVJ3WeAq6o38I2gefgFpCwfEM2/Uiy9L2AH5AJAVgSEbnj7iS5Fy2swIrXrYIk07sNraEFVrCCgH8El6bgHBsuc4KEoPopa7QpPilTVkWf@HS4ehPXLaB6kADiCFLtzfSIXlIoYuXxceW7gTKVJfM4106fEGgKpQ07sQlCU/WPn9xcMAzG5C8m4oTJOPC7xyc9gCwQRXhF6sOobxzeLdQX2BbLQlZBV9oH7ub6M3YdG9iU0A9l5bagGCyda81M8tQWsvi7hfEix5@aAqAIRrceXDxI8WpVBvreql7bSqQhI25e7jHa4j7Z@psspclhplSS1E0P4717h3zfefepNeZ9FpJjlsg58Xi@HhJ6wgrYdiSf5abIOjeCkq5hBSTyUBqqA7FReq1BI0OX37NhV/KBmSUT7JHj6gcG@BbT1IWmC5DOTIZQRCBaDBqPkQWFG2Ziist5dJ0OhD3rNEF4DiP8IvbW@Pgih7grNMFnerVYBQG3blkgbZcm2LIIqrbwb4Gd7HQBD@yR6DkLGvBMMkyP1JdxUjUFrNMz7IuBE/x1KZhAeXqTsgTfVKAwUi9/3yH9xC/j4rCeQDVGPhelToMmMUjHL5E6EtLLUfXrmo@FPBDggK6RaJJYUNwuPvTHe9QsjQfL0iWmPohKff3qj4d8dRADoLSqFnxChFOK6K6FNgIgWbwC2Q4fuuAnpMkR5bJCIiAygTY7iScLHO4O58uP1CJ3elaLH90LZAtL6zF7gOr8YvVAqa1kESgFsDiU4A3A9D0M9mbhXkoYC4kFFSbb4cCJtCQlmCMTyB4QHqYcsP08senh0m6Oj2UYdxCD3KuwJNMetuT3s6kF4cvhGhsY4MVSqDztNClroILr5JgFXB0OK@cTNid9JIxqc50P0034MA8B6A5ZJUcDAlwlhkjB1FcfCOV1sd3JNbZ1l5z//nu6WQs4lPcpih4z7Mtk/KQJsFEgTDeTaFHCkqU6mIjcHkzdcTzyFJ7Nk9Oj3e3nmWhfBLbCEfAtAwAP2IkTNTgzs8BQi29DfNxJ8tSJ1ssLbFHWLIsEzYI9Dw4C9N2dUC1MMfOcFCgrPIcJPBPjqQEjsjYnKziKZaS2Lvzc5hS82tM7Q/eFftFa63YYePiGgq7HE8ggwgu7zOY53xocmEDITv8NuHq3Mxe5/Os5BSZp/dA4h7lnVn8VK87nNtoWvTP7g9sUsrcGsNrRJG3iOuBYF6cFG3ulyJpbkQ6wFAcxhCG0zmZHzMknyN5UqwvYPGydPSPLcuHJNrJssi8LBuU6WwZhPYaO40amnFlUdyHMmyZBuqh9DJyto@29rF/PVaW9W3oNANdbXtATzRSCbs6@FzbhF@6zw1Xguled300MG0Dbx7EW5Bwqd4J71lWYocW64OeS/Zmbv428PJAcaMAXZzE72ikE82xpXZ74jX0kbfTvwItaWBdykDdXeOSyXK7a2qXLjjMDrlexU6C22MwB9PQoAUpC/Wgqan5stC36VpqLBy@4P3o@acMr/ZF3d43Pmmm4Y1pyzYKWbRtW8drsF3jWge2g/ds6R0lxtXYB6l20TA0Z02G0anuKYVXc13dmdJqBzyhTz659GPcD/84nRN0g2e0m5rTMjx8v0qT25ibPEdfkB9MKlS0IUdQHW7C4WRH9yFwZ18boW8qFbYYmdDCBVRUEiBHra/7KlQ6PSCUJEwy7olgTg8W4zb6l78s1BO4O4Y@gdeGthpCW9Eom2FEn7ikuQVAwHeIA@1@sX/aFJexcb0pWLa6R42MtHLN9w1qvAaR8ouSz@qayDah@HijC79UFap6bXNajpMyhzof9Db8R1RIepEYFh2xDWiKPStdcLUoT/qI3@BBmkecEh5FSvUobNAlMUsENPDAdFzr5CCz9UXEXUfXCYBUVN@KPqXB/JJpb0HPtEzNukJXjev/LO067Uhn0TVTkXqgHhjURSiFfOES6g1JA90@LGjcCbqFAISW73fzCwuHMxkRMQ3v4SBrFMkxD3FFTh9v722nwui0L0fwukl@Thx@KqtD4Np2F80FtjPmGeEVGalaDUBQ@CCeoFu@Ch6pdT1sDURHkkqkFEC3NT8Id//pYTmz7P7S8qyWiRxIrJlfVC7hINRZUKwLntViXgjtLUUrM5E0bBxfLgInTO0eSOKm3hUUB9MY0QhXuWdahYuvARUx3k5n@Qv4Z5tRT5VbI3BA6WgCQhYi4TDGizWmChcUGkEbwdDBrELSo45CsxR2oUG0yAyQGDCcGZnMRD9FkJ8Z2G4qy1Brp@bEAhsKaiSaXrQ9wZCgD73B7Qusy8VS3taxqSYCDQINNH6pwRtQ45G/Pg4kEbztCQmcUyYfy6JBa77fH4SBm2LCRgm46t2sgZB2COieY98MjJFupoBhNvGSuQGDICGHDQbcQRCBTAbB2NlUdsGvlpdTkOqM4HKVC/aIpdSNjdSanKKgTyqSFAxGkbwQSR5JDEy60WCpQjpV9BOXMDGgLE4iKM1HUOAISumU6iMoCARqGTBwEYOQfAIqGVHtJOJKBHGA92ISBq@qm5N7upBRLzY2Kqi4RgKnEhfmFz1dzBQgMUe9lJmM4Wh5RCT8YrJGgLxYiMwjERSlTBFQ8KwzkxFhrlMRQabRPEsXcyenX5rw4huf/cmHkuON2bpzVsH6IqVyS9uAgXvgOSIQby0d0N2lYRgn6TSSOcgINCQht56OK0FZfnetmLSg/WpTs2LE4ksQyAaoEXw8Rpa9vm@ua338ZIfAXbp3iNcZ1NUsq4AaAhwFOEYFEgMLoTYwLpvt/iCAg6m4InEzFp/AKJPnNt5Ffg3SfYfEfj8nYmO8@fAaMsAn7g6lOYS3bwoSNA/2n@Dj891jNAPsP/8UunAJ65Fl4a9fzWWOMajitmbx1yYYngFFAN7GFRpRV95Vk/ljoJ@/wOYjF/DT2HlCqh1CMJ5YSIdEF4bXNGyBjTelT0e6R@1I12sGABWpBnoGu9GZZmJzjPlrASr8Fk5ayaPU1FTgCBKKAmILYZudHm89P9k7PH5GLXfU3Do4erqFmEHBbGtOB9APehoOEMvSTT6pBu0Zw@n3Et8WhHXSWv69cvw9SgjLLxzmjQeATYppUuh0ibC@nOhn4HnwvATEUQJoECqaHX0wBzcq5AGYqIw7ByHvRV5qMRWKMs2bCWnCm50JfT7aQE5HbWnrrpX0gLA9uuzP4vwk5@N7AlomXTpMIxflqEuiF4ffslos0KsXkI7c4QAtYnonHm1@rd3WXdqQFrY@oNTNLmUiOEukoSBkfu1D/sEN7sHcK3DQzdM06eYDuTcUcyeFRZAeedt9Kxk3IiBxLL6MdOuLlSQWiZz5myAmREdjUmRclBnP7TXP7TXkxhkuez0tkBkXZ68nBLF5zWP4zfOay8a@ZMbFk8A@Rj3XhUHv9nCvONlCONehDsNuoq2S9niC1z3yu@yRP4rDkThfuLtfKBMNOymRiQknnD@FwtzpQLOlZmwbZI4n7WvoYP9zj6XfoIdmSr5646sYBE@U0gRx2ofz2ScuDC2kDMQE3JCWAM5Edhc0qQT4UgIhk/3ySBFZg5aWhVXAsIBbhCtuoq4kStquUBQjgchWxSzsdPxBTpDhZOZ0plepEAhD@SpqaGrla5M8owo66dbqOqFGCgllVorgsqosQwKJ2zVIpgF2i3Wg4hne/GpUZqshKufLZAY36yOrE26VswIEfQd6D4T6mdfm1jtSD3@FDxNLkYrla8Is7G9TeHHEimqxGNnTcPjyOVtdDbc84NETVirkw30UeAiFra7HvpWdLLQncHrEgSM6FMkKaQZVd5AFddOEQcwfHQOnfiwbV4tH/DGuBcJVmmuwrmDHYmpwWR/fh9PS8b0v@FJ4j6kjVYktAVM8jbxRyJ@8AfByqDn42jS@cIyM3KWXKFKGlJDedOa4/G1D9L4d4Pj0Wk136OjcAAwhHbtNL@xBHJQOenrYpy3CWRQYrnUH9zYZnti9tEQ8R5ADZw0NTgR@oM8cGj5t8CYULIFGNBpZeDPStIytx00vwlUgceX0IE@lPD1QaUrz7@bHAlDzClKhNubu2JJo4JlphvTxtLgj1h@SAXDI@ueZBmcnGa6c@nq4QMPnmFnN37iYY4wh6mpH56ARtpiPiup0IfkLe8QB/HWdtm@H4ED0GF3Q9ES4uDaKLYhv6zG4LZwRjyApgmYpmlIcpDqtfeUfQaLopeDtJETPdRh9EgRQZmIVMFjzFRBI8hKHEAu@0xA4PjnEKIoDSsEHalpsNyQIxBEs4iH7JgrxtXB0S0IvQARcryWxi5efL7TNr4UYo5QpX2ebLilFSZGxPB@MV1mAYe0iYFAo4kfpYA8lB3txFC7m@YBUejJI3Vf4idweWniR3QzQREs8sOhBQ9wJW908pJC4b1/zt5KJhTNfzIz0DxeSoBMFIRDN0rgXpgrRBj5X4KVrRVJwmdlP43MSihE7GWZZjoAKHOmCv8fBZ@iBmTPcrDCvopyS/ar61aQepDeEmMaApsbJuophEa2rrM5Wdi1SWX/rxERlRSK/nrOb1ixwdPEdcLSpDCeUuNiOEf@kk2WfdHAxRIRE5yi/Nebxv8kNHJEB@VU9HJFB/YKy0k6AwMPHqlg7RNYepXdMh3jz/iDHV0TQFKAiuG3V/Ffh8FRLS0KcAaFnIl1BEmbngJx9FN0u8GvcDEeHiA8KPqaQYghLnX3N8dAURC@UiwD7YO@Iz2MBpAAWX5MThY1QkeDME4PUpw6MyGTEfFafsAaHu0IWEmIUi@CdkX0X96YnnjJbijHG8WlyPg4/iZjuw/FfixZkvLAg2By0RiTmumDNiO/zuvtFV0ZD2W0gJDeQuwYF@HkjBDEhv5XzvhyQGoTyQqAdcH0gKhsIQdsXBtGwhe9tTA34fo8sg9wXwofbJt/wBb52z8GUtK0xmoz2z0UZEi9hIaIWDSJKzGwxqXeoRQe8TybLTR1JhpAAO6/Go8EZIssVZFwG5M6MOlOrCXSMdm6QNa7GdzSSKIunbEhPjW5pxI5PY@VxyTLUswa448Hf7UAojP7A1PlbJNWD5tbhfvhOUfFOHd21MchVbOcyd2NcGTkOGDsRe/FlfYjjHHfe85jm7guYynAXvaewE51vVtDFuyNfkTqpD6VXmAi39VsA3O2CxGvhK578V44JBK4SLSxEay5/gerYtlth6TV8RzXopLwAWSq7C4W/hIYZtugFQG3Nc/WxnsOEuZYJP30Nj/znQCXPYQ1zh5Z@AKlP8A2dymvtWovtRApGL92aypUO3sRktB1RDL6kmu8eQRuCR6/VadnQNzByddopIZQEOr9nW@aYWbiv6ZJe@83oRRP@m0Xx1ZT4iiWxqENbHvgbPUv59VVi9q6Y4Sgdzt@KAnFlKcbfSFBl4rWXNaBm1HV48ok9LVN7MvjAnNxEwfX8ybA2njj48D6NYItHLhdJa1sP2fcxb48HHWqAZl@08yOXQ/PowMTXUt5odNkC2y6t5VerjL//lsgQRwu9NySU2PXRAO/1x40BOI/7aU39WjdZEbvxc8MdAuCJN4QqxRIDR7vsaz5gqlhlmE3k4AHp1xPblMIo2zYnQ7oaThihRk1vEmNqiI3ePihmFWxMESzmBV0CrgU/m6zZtGx7wKrg6OBrP2kywBe5@CnwrQNatoUJNKmRakmb8KzCE4pOp/phHOPgrweb8nE/kW2wMxjmF8xfoIjXYlQLGPp1Xvqanx5nDgSLrOjAhM1XNWBGSLOmUEa5lQCgcQ5LcTiX2z1p8dwH6dj7h2i1oQxhxA5SQQxWkR@xkmoL95SkWWRPCbAE3ESPhEn7@nM53zKS3MI3NPieJ0keS1ajFHeHJiI@66WD5vD3L3T57pMNOujA6MAjNaeEI5ASqzV25wPiHhCUcHBniZz0dw6ghOng2ky4IwWaPu5rYfehjRSg@AFI6jgkM5yXItWgTGnR8S7YtzIdrV74a1gQXs/X/NbgL3QJ@j9czHrEe3OJKr5Mr4e5Zf5p@jZfiKFVErHANFFWnLwEjRB1cFxiik9xeqCASWoQ1kQymmYDgyovKLe5ArNAmVOmKSXLRuwSre9cfcqysfDiNSIxfmlAPjuuq7XgZgHdGvZvURnJ8iTDQRaB75gO3L4Ww1@h0Tk882B0wyxBbB0ZOb2SkILO/HA0bdzms0y9q1HObboBlbN4kCNmaX/uXqxzC/FVz0AVof8LPk1UP@nEszw/XDIgh@o7ChfZMDfeiEGpR2P7KjXKjoF1sNSIdneS1oFuYZwn7zgSRRsvxTqNYDBoh21quO7YxLZL@ccqWHNUBwWpOa6jDY8fakCBlw8L2hWL8FUGgLKMgKChMl/YpXhqZmB9o0wG40Gpm4wfDujsrJ9@Jh57j/Dz9FH8d@HJH2qH5ijbHEv@vhRI0RynqQmC7Sl3M9Wl4v0C9Z0p71R9Z9ojqO@C9gjqO9ue36q@gcX4C6oITDH0QB0HVfZN0KjxhVB@ILdTbDIMzIcz1M6X06mHA7w8cCo1Xe8zm9oeDGwX75iYXwKe55xCUHwkHPLc5HlUwQ0Kco6bj9RKHoYe3tjixvgQd2yUF1Pkxgup@fwF8qTJbdtijqYAxLxOFv3AK0/5IQNJTCXRIJ8lBvXDrDhP5eIEiG1XtL@4ziJZ1YKCU0W5DsYocVB7iXFvBEek6rR9EUrjJ8GGkti8JEOUOzDddBIMm59EtLrgj5OpsNXZ3FR@J2JqsbvSl4SI7cT3uZYUSt3xyFpTk7gzkGtEngj02MDeO8r4BM47gyy9yYw/S4Mqts9fFr8tXqp8JKxT@FZkeg28Yw8vewx3v6MMyN9bjAm6Nkr3KF2CVI/3kA@BfDpVf1tcKqx@YD/OsRcDBko@vX0PR@6zI7aNgn9rjLZkbgtIRaYJscNqacmXnZZCk/YScfoA@IIb@rjFIcye@ixSgB2kByjCM7TEQfbHRE5zMvYnMVkNJJC45nl4nQlK1gavAlY/TDbAZZgwIUoA/sEFElaWAtD5heVkHCktlS5a3AMglXmlzc8tJJ1JmC5kS0dTX/6ewnEr4rTtBoqDuWNpdvS/hf4LcuWr16D3f4A0IVOfKrMEp4OSi5ujQdjBs/l9vFwf3xTNKRU0cED5HN/pbJrj7FzMN2iPo9Gl3YDuRaoywmUUUZwe6LPXuNFobmpacetp0FV0dAARQQlItPLfoYl46B3r7Bmpo0FirgC7JMrhYVpeDLuNq8x@4tmWwDsw9Y6LIquGtELlTOHxBjFc/VXCjoHv7MOaB6zXLw7Zo0lb7Bltfipj@wiL4uhvhobDlW0sjQJ9Sft@gBS2ezq@4RZg8ea5ELtsWDI0m@XJdpe5b4aagyYH22GZpBsTPJ7PNMdiJ860HCUYVG0CmCivPiuERIBR/MTzbVNk5dvr0FTj8zzarIO3HSVdcQWRsBlh20ZtP2g1URjwq8AgA9OzyXkxtBDhiajfWdYdmsiL7YGCccgJJysb9aFg2Vqu85NZE9WMeCaAOGOdjI1gFNtQnABDiqZxMRNzTvNh8PUZaMxqAbDMoQMdK9K@QaNBU06028TyDh0KCu0XEE328xTSm@vDdHGvhaMLFQLT5KUsZTKLlqbiWayWbclRzBxsFjHAIZj00P6r/x31H0MByELeAwxmMMCX7rbEm@@p6EL7hJFOtURCFlUBPtAfmp5m6fbQNcd/24QQW6L7t4XsDEFj8n4pvJPiOKphXDvL4Q0nbD93SNvdcG8CKurAvAsHVYyJnwpWgx3Xt8U8y0xxDMbN@nen4TJR6hTjDkQcTo7@noCpGJidGFp6cJuAR2e8snzbALBOOi5meQql8zfYaW1vSEy0Z@PmCv4@5CxudegDG4Fw6hJk2FgXRG4PdIdnBtQ2tofMn589O3J@ERhkeIDQgEzF1Ef4kTdjtZDu@UQCeBB3BBV/Q3wkDbBfKDiAk@0Iyu1Pby1d2ChwcuOrW/R@X8iBsoUn4jb4Gbgww2@dG1@FQ5svZom4p9LllThdDROxkvF99qllod9LvqI/tf@JRGbf1uXDcoISe/txJYF2Vcya5XwF1qjRRouUUcedGht4wgLGJYCeGRfLdVxr4bs2yHaGvXgDBKJrTrsHVYL@MpBgPIfaqWN0qNlAh0Ozd3A/g8sAPd79JnEB2hr2Wzq@I4baKzimSeseaCQHkFSIWqKcw6OXBnE4IwP0fI5bPcl@3JGCscWzIr0ElR8ADOxIOIOKMpH9UjQM@sOdTUHrdFPCi6aQAjYL@s9EoKxe@JdszEQVLvzrOAKVr1Cbxqjeg1EKjWdTR8LQ4OVFtjjd2M4VXzlCsxtxfk8zyO6Na4F8wzIm8i16uMjvhnF8JcM3zoV3NdF4xomlp3kfNvL61OQBUzT5gR5@cCpsYL6GVws3LQe7kfOctoCFtbkFKieicGcUT8tXLjljD4jHX3PlNkR@NigfPbol2roeHQq8r4Upk59rc8yukK4maENACopAaL/kaH4XJkk/D5nQEBQvPNdxqPCZug9WE8ed5GjIHar/vJx@8wla0a1G3h@NnD7qdU4dYR7BJuF2ZKtu2j/ewPeTTTQ/VnlcD26l@XbtRhyDm1NrbCT2d9FJqxHf4bU0pX8zXuMzFEmXlsYf0zrUFsE28dAmHydqFsOA9I5gM2CB08aUluczxi4f@nOOqohNnvwOF5jeGd4QI45vgDdqDHc9KViuFwPU9RTXI9qJzPQy5z5A3/PGnWa6NkySXFIzx2LUu7Re@HErMf4I5NmLcdcadrEouNIPacIDKrOnU5a7Acuhrbl8wZ@3FIHTvsMh4uDjX4rsFvRvCeGnVgCKjqyIFX6R8My3iSN6sY26K2xkvAYs3RTZijqI8lAlaMF7P7x6jrSqTx39Eh7HBpao4yZRXgpWvpXYDjcmHh3uPz/dPW4e736@e3yySylpI39woHg4yJGlzL3BGwssgTfpRu@6U2IvHQPmcZxx6PI41MBP2rbnsT1Qd3VQx680SKkN9djCNffCweK4F67uVHn6Uy7M0@F72mnsGnhEaIhblaB@N1wB58vDKVfixA9zIJ7wR6UfJWL/srsY8kxg5jwG@SeOpJZN97sShDjZgFOK3fVuUAIU2sTkGnPw2jZF7LH1odHkEN6XEFyIgAIAxOOu27FC7xOJjlVoeB1kThQjsaz8YnjQvbfz7Ihnu0PZsh1eL5QhNdO2LmPi9oRICUhyg0kri28rqfpNTIeCIAvctwBDh1qa14hXKIf6QU5V8rlf3pUG4SL239NtBd/iSP63POc9e05/7qVw847t@xebRGScu6kzdBN3wc09QTf/CrrJA3VTGRVERt/uOPni0@QCffHv@QT5ggPkonSlv5tD47/c89wPPmb9C9@x8Hd/DGcuAU@cyvHJd@4W07tf3oGd/6@cGvm44yIfOkXxD0cn5h@dELdEfszhiWQ6SbuPUfLYP@QGezQ1BeYf19/dLe5om5LJfK41sdE2uJZrctN8eMmW2In8sE30EzvoJ7aV/61th19c1zlnAcLqzt92/BG1jhyOmKho/qN2wge3j31gi3t0t/7dRPn9fKPb9nFLuzNG2TM0pOGYE8Wd3CJN3ObdOzaxDZyfdOF7fIn8xQ7z4HiL2PceNcb5m9HF3OHbzHjKqe3v3Cg4J3Vwc6UnLv7jdwZO3pspqDV6JlHA5WsTG@KFHiX5uO5m229q23rYgqGxlC4RixrxRVlTaWwbvF2P5gY8eyBN99EEytAYuwjlZNf4fbEoMzHQZs6EBCvw/385bRWQID/g8Q@HrP4eD1n9w6mRfzg18g@nRu47NZJYzg1dJ9cyrByIZiaTb0D6p9fI7hyyl0@3Ttnp012292L7O@zLwxfs5dbzU3yT69GLJwf72wy@u89Pdlnw3ln6fK47uOWeQdfv6G2drPOFfL7ECPPMWxdK7ETrs6d2W78G4tlwtf7jHvcolu41eKrda90Z23w5aICbWTxxaoJsRXytybc44YnrFlByH9cR/bs8sYx0m6frv3IQBhu94yE4wM3X9kgGoX1ctKwUHNoAeBtCAY3Gl2Rp7zQurZPQ0lGYaLjg89EtCELhsxO29XwHry/e2T/dP3x@wvYOj8F79CVes8N29vHamCcvMIoAnx3u7O/tb29RAC9AXmFoW6MD6/cVQUFwapX2VXfYvlIGJmqFwjfxWo9ELGbZ/qkIlyWHVnh9TwdICtfd@WWnaHACwl7ZOv70c5Rq9DcsHsebe7FB@CtV/BMIK3k8NAK5iVcD1AiGREtZ5QypP2YrGF2jt@imyJ1lPnKJ1okNncW30YyIC9L8ZbsksPmoIaNlwI2o/Itg6@w1CMipZDK7QSgbkBtZD/zc0LDa9T2Y9LG4mBX1yIR/S6tLSPHG2X2rze8G9wOA7vmubsrWczgAGoREAAdAGwwGeNqVvo9GElYWEEMPFX8IWOUBr/uDvRuUGvGA6//T3pMtt5Ek9yx8RaupEbqFiwBJiSTYFHVwduSQRJmivBNBYTANoEG2BKJhdEMCRGHC69thhyPWO571jvcIH7vrsF9tx643wn7w@8w/7BfsH4zzqKqubnSDnCP2yXgggaqszKyqrKzMOrJEwl20hCgQhNaL1KWu0Rm7/pD7MXGtibWDG3Z9n4qEBI9BcgYDueRKR@LA/hd7bLgrC5AmaME@jGzpVMTbbiANoNtP3X4UGpZj42owuCDe0OeTWicDF9w9Whce44WlV3iMgMhu4uPljnjwKTY4KbqwdGE6MyPJhyp3X0z83mXLQcm7CxTx3B5VGg9MuWztXsjA3QUGvgoaQFTR9QWGFRpF/Lgpogn6QpStMACJBJfP@EiHB3HuTbpeooDwdawX/ps3tmjkclxEO@JD3KkTdi8mZyPcCHmNMagozAU4MXRS8hR3o7gPrWQN4r3hMzwMMUYGP3R2E9R050FSFCdxBFG053Oodly6DHchVZJ4Phus1NdIxYyi7e@Qr@XRNkkH3WTlzYUYzxkPMWBkpzGGeekbeLBoFhEnaHltFwqx7vjICGvHH2w6u/fvPq989GG5VaudsFpwe7x5wYcSeZuFXHIYHursJJ0GlCNNIC2Ekw6WlucZWVviKJfIwHA59cH43ms3VR4vqy6m47N26XRKfPvW4VIVum9CIjQJT61Yu5WNY0myTGVahi0QxLoTmMXIujKlTDiVvt7DxzqwF5rQIkPUI3S8Rqstn6/Rol3jhh5oloKw07i7FX5bPrAgJIo@lt4ftQ@su05p165JKBpMqjktqaLLEnPdFrWih0povlpAd385OtDfl0e3uZQ7nh6@FLb7S7F9Kd4qpXxcPC1puC6P9qMlaHly@0pooe7lfMQ8SS5iU5KuhLN8bUXK/AUUP1zoOxp7gAbn3lEwipFq1CbDAUaIs3hRHFijAraOJjaInh7d3z88NEx6mHMbyoLewycie0INIu6rMtIR30MmZVdVRpP8xMaTTBFP8STJLhvMmY2XoyqEDVIW7aGURfyEeN@fitsRPLOQCYEXr1khypZLcncudVB4LBDPj/EklBF3mlbBQmY1V3jy4SD7pGTidiuzbRy@9EfKmPGmIlgXLVWPZzoiaQjjdOCe4M53dv99m@3jbUmHDSzv9ydUYTyE38V4@cZTIDzCneJqsgeXdIvsUjqzQlK6ItuOruUlLeyvL1DqgYm5sIU1tS6MY8Ea28fXpJlDy5o4DeA@/0xkds/EeqdU8ZSyo3eoHU96VnIKAiMT3GBjT5cKKN6aiymMWkPNk44yyPWxdo24OZZctvCMkcDdzAd6Byz4jZtp9ZAmBdp2KanKN0OKZ4kEJdnmmZWRmYD55sbG2kW407WQxStfFzfPIWn9GZ2NXrkaynAW0lEhkNwHj8syPxaAJU3ngBfYs@SASRUEUydjTknUnSYjnT/ghd@zBmYOnh2Vcb0oTdU2pinesrHzjKRjJ5CFOmhDWFWUR81C68@Xk0OFfCG9q1@eHg82BML18PkX/FDtYTBCVYmPjrc5Kiq45NshnoqLsAQ/1a4i/XKEPcK0F0bsvh63@DfvcOMdaaa4FwUv8Vy/I0pVw9EAlJKJ21DVM3d0/hYXuN7Skinn4Z0AUdYvG3sv@IzKKqf0AjpEQEENBAPEZTIN1PyrtrpfCHnbeHywwK98IoC2gemoBixeLxrg92zjqkJZppU4DewTlVThJPk@tkq/wel4L8EfDWYqvcbpPe@Vj2GyReqOwPLaHam0XQE5gXbAM18qwxTAtFbr92dtanaVfZuzwYxRSe8IZsC3HAQq9Sqn4pkqmXQsyk7ipBYngSelklYEFE5MfqTLUuh5L9vUyQZPC4CwWDaG/qBVFeenblvCd7TFFY6IOxLKe8NegToFRSxGJaeEPQwtK0ToeM9vVekApVBA6JPFHcsDac@PC@jAkA76tS5/kVBxMWIA/womBKu68CLl470XKOFjL@xOPEO9Hp@QSgoMsoLvQxkH7xqHB0/2k6iR4zbaKFRKHthDETwWjFF15JAtQ4cHk@i0zYnyZzr3tce5EgX/VkDDYKwB8c90riRAKFo4LI3zt723xjFM3iPVKVbPbolOlzVWdah2g8kwOn87fUvdOwVLrwoicNuYV3GR4PZCs4iRKCxsKQ60F@eeeW20K9syrEJMhVKIylTE5gjEjevUmLfnBfmqr9Sf0HUwMklJK62IUSJQEwRo8myPccEg9KA5uqcKZEx72Q6@8pliDCelanUhuWTcsm1R3JMqaZHYJYmU8ohsxURYwhSeaggpVkzNNnqB8dZ/Gz@fLicVnPo3096Oam2M3Sy6UZtiaNglYFZbWjbvSmh17hWS3xYGnOjB@D54IcYjBgT0nqbNHZbxBBjJ9wKYUg4SjAfQAhyNggQgD5MFQCq/iLGdzWU89DKKZHMcj8dFdnKoxOgyimRTiZlOdkU81lO90Q3AOuMHSfBLGxxBbX7N7DkQmwXCeYPVSBcUokjuTJtpWvzPzqAh1TRDgDy25Nd6qyVe19WLLYVPtojOgai81iCogyicCk5reno9na5PScauVjwNoTGVAgacqZnq4r7gSCKJpNd4U4uHFV3a4s8x2lpiagSV09JASYRyQCtJUB41MSyAIghZcTizaKA8EpOgpWxQTfgJXsea4lUbjQq0lA2qjY8FrJUsrEnQUhp0Qa@Roky2vTJob1jLO8/OsWN1dBopb@p1JxHPNDJoBYyhCIaHbmgJ6J5/4ke3jdjQom9V4AeFdn1TRMSWaeDgb9xSpg8VkKa2zoIgGyNEbaHZUn4GYV6O0s232DBXxmMCHl9noPlNBz0mCL0bDI7AJBiRRoZwaOQsJk0xvWm41DQymnQZyTCNlXP4OUfr93jlnN2dKu07mmXTnpvMVjOhRaFOMln4Rzs7si2qUdD2jcxPUzBPOIKRkcRRjZOWfBI4JpFKxSWO8iDo8mJnGXE1pbN2DOkt8ehmGgfupizWRRYENK2L@cANlUUcI3oJeFmldBzSqVrEcePSOKTDtoijcnk@yJ/Kqss7l8bBjmAWjtqlcaAELrapuXIOCOb818wStUR74LUokeqWO0nRUDjdxK9Oui7SVTXwviBhSMBPU7@y@BCGuS7rA80NulR7oNOx2B6WzyNpF6Zi0tyrvMBcx5L2wnhh55ZSeQVWG3lN41oY9WAiqPYHanxnDP6Ui55aJBEIad0DnZhq93QMLhL2ZlV4H9IAIZzAf7uNR7PabVoZenJ48K3DO4/aj@88QidqhXUULt/gaRk6rrNabZiQxastbTpT5Bh41AKrUSA9rOURfwLNPs0i9HIsllo51@DmJhtQSMmh9aLq0HttvAtZVdoZTONEyKpam4HusYgHpdTNyivTjiH1GUzWSvhru8AJwbCcCE4IRksuaM4Wl38@5BMqz4fPIwbsGMd8JzNs6fw@x4tLWkHDqLx6Hv2eN@7gWZKKClrKvYhH8NF3o@BUeORCrKDHGLQO/KJWM@7KoLji/po76GLI20mfAt@e@QP3rNNzq6PTUaEfOiI8jVXshxjksoCHqR4c7R8@bT/Bd7r279HNCfw0Ke/owaP9g2dHmPMUstZE8v7h4cFhmw6oHz57coQRQ1NJpg4osMRgIiEB9PjgvTsPNRj@bQom@UJICP4m/BOhfMqGP2pP6e@MrnmU@ShEmx7hoWsqWJTSykbkn3nBRD7ehvEn5ARfxpsnuCkDtOSrxhSQxsLlT5EXxzqda1DEx3gyigiUTsBbqZawkyUY5iw8wQIUiygEu51O01d5RRnz8CJfMLJSZfGCDBYriPtd/ZBGBw6Tp7Nh15LoRCDP8rk3BEjcbSpOon5lszi3MarkiA4NpQsXazBz1Cg4ajG7pGhBcSq9oD1ipC@7NgvywjtA0Y0S6oT4ZgoV4B3EplEq@fZ5QX8gSmSBVuX3o84N7Q59Eka8X3NF6yMOa8rnfIE@Coj6Jm7gKBnhn0/0TSkSMLE/RZc5jvHmuWoz@i8ryyvMluodK@TH5@W97iqeHrkHDN@JLA70QjH7YrkT212CgTZmpHs8mQfoxd6YqDARZBkPoyY0VDSeGXyDMIxUc0HNW/h3KkK7dvEAjQUCZ@uwpsm5HI4SLwmFEQOQm2fumttxGBu@lqAODjPEjg5Rz4L4QIdoZEG80iHWsiA@@5hB/L5VKsnO2zUaGxt8mjnRnxnF/10Vr1Qk7I48Ch0XBnx6cTkbM5J9xiGgSw5eB9XnbECuc3ZzKWdJ1J/9B@DWcYlSFSLCjC9hewnmz//Q3OYVuku00t9xDTUFhcaJ2PLiK8y4XnhPiLhkSdwlTWP7xRJspil7MbvsD2KJ@CBHaD77ZQImW2w@kf1uqPaTO1xX4rL1@FZDGsF/LiJwvgyCNpeX44uijfIFXsxubCsssgYxAgZZ00EaaZAskm@XklzV8dUzSdZ1kNXLkPzsV4KmmL8yIH6sIEjXisbMBP3vxECjo/lQKAs0ZEi8U/Mk3vXNBT9J8qAXywJ/EmOnIq3lfH/@nTTfcclM@D/KFE4qoMuX7PbMhv@ny@JYy8XxIaOoVHLbrcgQpVIuxGc/jfng5k0Ps2WD5PM/ubj0an7pP4hLx9P8rpy42WqQyNIqUB0PSmZS0WOFjfsPGkClZHCjTaNqzGlDDudicWEsWYG6yhY3zpLZDZk9y8xeU9kp5HM2sKSVhPH1yDDa4RcGyTSKv9MtXza4ZOauo1ttNldIt3bZWBcXzKFtlI0jruJoRs9uyuG4kXAyFlGLXFsYe/MCWcHNTOcndMfu6dDFB1rDYFgVL4D4QW3/LHjh40Q1rmGYi@qLMM8b@jqmNSEgP85B9/UOHqgAVkVQET77zX47Arrd7uRsMsA9NEf4VRgYqVbDkHHkCA4nZ6HAiTPu3Yk/gBo4aKnFJiK4eSPgkmZhMKUvRT5FOovsIslajc@NVykMHSURb92xP4qImLPoC2DIJzJQgYS/o8FKEx4vqJ8TIg5F64j6PPSHnqXB4yuufllLoLgIJYdLNUky0m2i4SjjCZDHk7MEhnPR43Q2xuGcaog3fqzVcgNbzkO5McYevhCibkf4odEQMegotAwiETeIxkksjfK6za1EiJ6AeJ4lIdbLjVUkNMIsClFEkaHVyXK3T2GL6FIr4SBsCpp6ASzCGL1o191VqB1kKL4c8zc/@fgfTPu8VpNp9KaOP3TBZ6AXSWKs@PMoeCJ/a@jRPxF3FVO4/zHGzah7Xtc/c/GFmkhDDcKVgxk6EDGfg6Bh0KpgAPomOLG0WDCSIApWrXbn/n3j6L3Dg2/jbSheRCApSBVHIdg2zBI3O5VM5IuDwQgiJGER5pEgjECSiUUoVSsEUzWm8Dp9SzuBBa313T@j1qK1/ABPuvO4TCHEbJOD@uA6IZ6t1dGqjpASjP3w3T9lzMGIT89mIw5GphBM@DryQPjlUqS1UC@GyKb36x/@JZETN0rA5sN1lTOddJ7RT7nHYkGWZLZSb@XWKkGGGiEX8YVN9L2fEbKQH@mWirBwRdeKCkl2tX/8twbhwM0H6D2tpJHAU7oQ0SeMSO0eUMvl4qtciO/7jK/n0y6AjqgzS1bxEcyT1TFeGrK05NoFzffrHwqOAd6PcM9kCY0bCXYLmZ3xb3rPUlnRHXn9q@HP7eEf6UjFNdc8jDxRZeL5@FfxMNWryaGTWb6vaKMzxVpmhT/@ryzpozPmMHowAjij1bsqc6zk8PzXf6PwTwtXphcIzG9@8ulP4zpOc2s2za3Pp/Fomi7WYprH@5WUSnofpwyzNM3til8mySRG7tTRfuYh@EVeu0@TjT3NG/Ig@mrQTy8Y9nlIPpFI1ICfXjjk83B9X@LKHOzpauUM92nuMJfYcwZ6Cv@NHDZhMP6rPhiny3o@d8zni8XfE3I0@PDy6EK31GrCwlkl03bHqNN/jMyL/3fT3OjaD5faYsPFAYsK0KHXlJA9hJru6CP/PP2m/Jztmji1LoItyBppVOqCCrgm7iDMIOU43xitBjYduHsZVHa/GpHCvFYbenzpfjLqoddB@3dn5HmMafsPHw/I1ozfob4EaxvcFb5tQ@EJjonlFu3ghAvig@go5pB0NTACdA/cDfq/o6pbqXMK@RtX0lgGAZtEV2g5HV2hXEdEeBKleivTqWA/NXMg/FxpIPauOuxdYWOJOlIc2TjnQuX9vZ8qjaRaKUhiT6EsXYzzn0U30BEj2iuniB3CpstH7SR@KUcqmSqngNyp@190bZEil29LamB5mH/w52qi80I8y9qD@uCVV4r4j49jYsPkzoCa/uSvhMCyb8QqI5fyX8iOD1lD5RHHmewSdHLI/OyPTRTt7Ebi7ObFTpbAmOtjGQ8eG8@e7h8aB8@Onjw7wgUZPTCi8sHzHT12u1kvkwObXCRY8GWb4OY32J3V8li8/LJfathU/b/6FKvPaEuOuWpqzbS03I8S5eqy3JI2oq64dAuJ9lkoz4sWwB3TFrV1nE3RQuBAPxhGOF5DD74IMF6Y4IDPYm5j8ecr07rXLQgznkt0/TdZLW0xJn8xAac67ACnbmD/Oav/Lxm/HcmgJasZ7t45Wbt5jB9qIUN@EuhvW4ISK5vNwhdfrBijWXQaDBuFFUOtvxq0/ooxg3iV80XIa7jh0B@NvIieIjBOvCEuQOPjbH6AVgUG6MDY9/D9pUd3gLclcoOXS9svwjYiagtE1dHMMK/tmYWCfzYKxpHxZuB35Hd8R/TmuvwVzkIM9RB6XtZj1Efj2YPoYIi2Qw2jGkYBf9ffpcZwSyE0OUD4QXU8GdYoJIQ37OHSNR0VdF8Ca6dADqrWawNYG6tl2bh7HHoYQsp8Pu33Tbpg7Q16Tz1sXLTwDBXt/AFe5jOB@VMTT5itGI@DyNvmK9HynrGKpEEt7hlFsWBWGfCbi7SqX9Re48BTafjeFO2emHhwSaypU3ges0qLxFDKtGmJ3cJzWv0giGJ4edxCFODNm0QJrCM@pMPCi3F/4xrhM14env4UTJQMQyQQH/FPQTROIELEDWicsjvGgaPu1YAROBPr//VtDMGF9iyY69vy/LGPZ5nrm9sYP5tqgg2K3SSWb@ubmDPhB9fxVRi@P67Xo@QITgCQO4QeK4JxgC9UB50XdNADDWrwsFH@qjIPTYgOhi0ZUBx2tDHV0@KvOz6Ha@/5IQFgydrJG38kmqicENXO5CSs8lig6Od@GE68jVub68QQvT0gQXtBNwHaqAFmDP9WI@ZOo7OBqsVWdCre1KYYLWfy0W2KlAWDkuQMYyG4eC4PBPCmTaIDTZmoKbSCtVXmtPv77z68c7R/v2xU6hsIzpdIFKylNS5nlyifDlkKMcIiPHyrnZvrLORWWC7u1Yq2YH1Pb/aSzrBEAObWGHXtyCo6VExYz4wY1FoPdVVZvYmk3l/B81Q43JCVyRgjC5uyceXIX1kxUaSR1gqKYMKugzJ2QV09gV@geBaAcnUFtIDQbm10eTDcP0muuXO1UlFjapu@VUCxViq7fBfMvAdz5UujeDgZJrRtkcaOaxRByWFEG1ZtV4ukF6pm0zh1iu@ExWYX5nNlILyyJva5fIZn2EcuLG64o@DuTPafNZE7S9Ag9nG9Zdsiofi//1O0m/P46N7AiuxznOLeODJsW5WV@j5HubKK7LFBsTfVCBzNe6RcIydqqgKdoDer0rNhvXun4FhYb3QaI8s@pxNIXcdZs8@B5HiEZ0VHoAy9I8BoNzGtn0iDH9DGYGPUnj8fYui6G7hP9/6jh@9Blx9iDIgwOv6gdeNarVwsgjdBu4QORuM27h88eoKz/diu0qz/LkzXol3GriJSxcV3vN1D3JdNrFoNRyFozhMvErUP786O3JPHYI5ZRReaIGlkufrOHD5Fi@ft9DZyzGTngo104hDU6djrN3nTeR46r6wTuxnBv1OdxAaQcBoNwh5BIQcv@aVa3R/CbP3e0aOHTnHHNRCrkzEqiqWOEg4QFBIYC5PID0@IDj55h1IV8d0KEhj4lIrmbrIuOzV3t9icz3P5eRi4PY7KUYwFuGdNykLixs5ilzbHsRTMRp6DCTy1fWv/yCxD2fHEszGR3iGYkdLigIGOpMHihpqCpsDZU4RxnPXr1ykNi0xCx2msrtq4hTMHbHRPE9DywBo352PX6VmqId2RXyX31psyLTJOGtVGzR2Gr71xWKvfbKxu3LodjNG373lh93oIKsRx8dk3P5pdx8t2tOV7Egz61/v@ABeVrq7f2Dzw7/7u@1tPb963up3fqZtl80VI7/CORzoDY/e12KEHHTvusnQRE0PA2XVrI/dlUFvvrXY3Vzfrt3rerQ1vc3Vts7vhrW11tra2uv31zU5v65Z7a6PbqWFoRypSPaMNfpPFH8n2L0c2zzDbbKxu9fv1@s1bvY2t/lZjdW1tvbO50VtdX@9v1t21tZu9xmZnq7Pcaov5KYCClXoX5460Bn4n37grLOh2Udr@Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<'4o'6o@<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
#xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
12-23-22-21-12-23-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-22-21-12-23-31-10-12-23-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-31-10-22-21-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-12-23-31-12-23-30-31-12-23-33-31-12-23-33-12-23-31-12-23-30-12-23-12-23-31-12-22-23-32-23-33
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._V[];=>+u 3>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Triple Threat code is on line 134:

```
12-23-22-21-12-23-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-22-21-12-23-31-10-12-23-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-31-10-22-21-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-22-23-13-31-12-23-33-12-23-12-23-31-12-23-30-31-12-23-33-31-12-23-33-12-23-31-12-23-30-12-23-12-23-31-12-22-23-32-23-33
```

The code can probably be golfed considerably.
It is [translated](https://tio.run/##ZVDLDoMgEDyXr@CGBjRVbo3lR4whPjClsWooTdo0/Xa7oK0xbgLs7Mws2R1f9jL06TQ1qsVGjV1ZK1l2XWDV0zLc6Do8IQzRDgZrhq9Y964aa6sMnNs9WAQunAmf/RMvzQJnCr3CKPswvWcRAhqUb3QglJwwSVOZcplwyROZ@JxzSRjQ0Y9OZiwcniUeZw7vXMy7@FrdKeK1z8LN@UaUb0XHuVrsrJAAhz4IVS2MRUQkqIhyQSnNowxuKoosK0RM0Gh0bzerrloGMPxvjMAvMHY4TV8) from this bf program (see [Brainfuck constants](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants)) (`.` means 'print as number' here):

```
>->+>-[>+++[-<++++>]<<]>.
```

Comment: Update: VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .000837 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 11570 bytes)

Answer (score 5):

## 240. [Nikud](https://github.com/bary12/nikud), <s>11454</s> 11211 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD5B/fLFsjTJEQCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZBkEQLBNgAKJGtZtfM5NbEE7sSZzJxjceJz8wkzrVvUhUnlcSTil2u8nxNufLJP6CdL7dctzz/YO5aewMgSJFq9cSpuiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FrqqO/zVr@J4kRPbnA1M2yOe7nqk5xiXuiOSvRm5rxpuQcnFYgi16wwmI93y3GosTmRCLP2KHFma0QM34tkXumW80R3wUwgZO/bAUUfEG6oeWAwIRR7o5tvRW49o9mikWj0XIHOEnKjg2Z9oF0Ttup6jap5hW@CVJ@SZZaqjbk8lAKE7Y0f3aPQFAlFoFzTMsk@RkMe24@qYvKa7ro2OJULq@mjszZpgKQOE6hj2o90nn60ErhDymQo5G5v6dCUvcpY8N3SntxJClskXZ4eHq64K@YZgW@TwZv7kHHnmuKqprsafJ7sTzz7yVt0LZHegWypRxIqorHoWyZ6j3ghSIo6u9vqGqYuGpRGBDHVzrDsEXUjfdqDJPN0sZ8vZzu4ipKhh2PLCcyXaRnAR1Rm44Glf6mDUoSXGht4jfcceEdVyryAluZJdwGO0lWV00CCDgGjklQuhezpxLWM81j3mCcXVHeoNKRPTsC5iDPtOHLs30QxrAHA61Ot44tEyuTENgjXJ2MdhEQ0kTmuBgUEWTu2RHm0LF5AXcu2Odc3oGxqrHH3q6ZYL5XVFYkDbXRmmSXq6CQEWsWsZ4tpk4kacuqY6FDUxhpWLqZDRhUkMoo3HhHlBMSBLh9ky0Uf2K4O8AX9z6JLpeERcYwTenmb3@7pO3ujjIQSP9ewYgUsbrxQrtCV0gLF0KNr@ybeg0jysS6sP@eqRbgQOMkEzTIurWjbUnUMsdcRQQRvPaNEhmjBE37ZFdO/ZumslPXJlOxekq2sqlhkTc/VBX52YkKLRx7YAJDBcMrLhDS1oEcgWBPawIjBuTCy2tiCYTNC2@hh6JbatjbgCDR008ZWjAnI4rt@InjEC1DC8pEt01TWQXEEQV7d6FC3GISGzobTRFieXBvQ6qIqJQ@N2dYfiPY2XYCkgSjVE1NSVY3iADliKXXKiqw45c3SdZ0iqu5o6RhSNJgmJ2ZiChwURKVbW68mD48MkYCcLIapjwEYnd/bNz2MqERsk0anB3eC4WuzgyQNynWijmRFMwOCxk1J50nhHXKnd1uGeyl1p4MxjEGsMasUkkj32JFUYQwYFDzIoqWhEk3CpiGMzkjCpr7RBpM8wqB60BlAA8kWGlkybOA6S9kWlqhdQaNO2BlCfUFhnYrEmL2ahCQD/em6G6Jc64gBrI/uK1vDZEDAE/gAaIStstKEVCuMN9EO/RoN0XducUDgI6XrYGaFWICjGeNQnX5C@apgYBPwxKpZrR3cBOTHMxOphy48MS@@JJMgGJTkOdMRLSE6FSKkD9IZRhLDQTAEwNIRNi4pe73/793qDAcSzq2m20/PR9QtAdo2OiyrNLIxsBBHWtlSTZgvgMpg6Cw4JXKqm0aMkTrVmfhI0EzTVK3ti9gjtqFcGdLmhCpRWB@qgeTpDcnviQR4zZKReMHJoMMyFgo/ULjQsTYCmTYstkPv70EoadHOKM8Jo4vXLRBgfkKQrvUjtVFM7W20dMseL/HZCkgY1QDhxmzqBLXkb5nyxuzROuJ7q2kYvNp55Q9tSiKARTmvYY91KJZfiSGaSTjfJi0imU3zNaGhi37B6qWQdcLEJCSf5mtbQWkb1vLYSPJokRHOF0WB31VMazyGpoZ3iUhoBZyECJftC8E0RP9vtYJWjtxhxxopZdbtkDnHKtyBe2oggQIdE19T1cSoryjySCYRbW270WFfSlTj8AleN83QynkxHi05jgJIuFRQ765lhI9kyx0NkNqBSLHcMNNdB3NVUwB4XRzQP@LkM6VK8psMgUBZKE6/0JFDtLhDSAI9ol2RdDsMLSCj9GBZdaLkn671IRwYiAH3Zc29QY9NG1oDmCUceIB0WJqoOoGkgMCvILisIS4m6LBfpwgKCgrF1dVIWugZ0AuxuQNN9nI@UDcBzCoOB2FgnidCekTrDUY3xBYsOg2OaSkZAHpwZ0XSkOUB8dDagYCIT2v9cYHqJ3SdZQSkUlvvYjS7mOdKu8BUQ6TfSrT0JCx/tTEhoSB94bFO1BhN1APTCtiCIqmn62PMJFZTE9YAUrY431FHwB0/RHcYS91fTpoNIwBst0kAiz1rPHwpVpC4@zy4AQ4Z8HxMESM9wgCzBSL6SOgBcriTOvUSQpQy85DZkIeAAAMn0qa5NPKBqgMBXQ0MbAs5i7ixGF9kgtJo8OEVTB8ou9MOkMTNy854SE6XQCbOxMQoBW/RmPDC4YlTNJQfa@FGH22NW3dGaiO0wizAQRFxFSRUB9z4Q58i27DWRQkWG0SLIsg9rB@DETpEjhoErYLtoZw3Z5LCJoM2AakDPB/wbet7YrcI4YXjDSVcETJHOnNmRd2whskieMzM8m5m7pt0FsuxC/5SCFCRt0jWmKwWibmEbvnJjl8CA9V3SgJH79QSwLpXsu0Awqfs@Ake8OEq4aRTsyQEgBRKholJ9l5LiQyAqpzNLS3FLSMllCId9l@PBgAHDqvkcmbflbL4Cp9VcIlg0M6KEUJLraNQgRHhSjB7BabZinywV7Y55jH3CcfDoq6arw9uamCZaJxajcinGK/DkOvbJJ0DaUjQ5YzQ2Dc3wOsyX3Lvn8xRkCwQ8ZJv6yDPxEOYTX5IWgaAAjD/8MGjRs08ps5vioSCfzJcS1h3Hdli63tCxrwh1QLBYtFL37RFSd/KcMlzIQYNMa1go2/tjKR1K1bUsRDimUn45mRRf2YaVuk5ubW0lq8kmjJhbWztgqqNpB01pMO1Qk0BNCCeiiYbIUBP6tmgIdDtPzltBzFP@HLvDFEf7N8Y4pbaq1dx5Rm3J/lvBNw/1DCMGQAv4gniSfKOBRp7nmldQULHbXy79Po56p5pjjP1K@Fy9VJndr4UcrQZoONtBwaCGzMvtdTJqOMBdgDCgDVNOst3Kts/b1@1euj1PZjA0X1MbXSgUpJcaiQPHngAbwrfyVUE@5/lWDpiPbiOZTW6nUmUBxDiQRPhPy3xaZbWdSuowGqba7SRUql8/LW3o0PimGYXnw6qCfCDDA7x2KilelyH9Ln/Op5MQlk9mQHRrJJNQMxpWgksLjX1pqYKOn36DVcx@Oh2j3RukUrxvDKfghkLvcvCTyZs3SLtYHN0Qw8yJyri8sQ8gHVkBrIieK0Jr4NXtE6SjS2l8ZveZVLSPj4NHhzF9Slvrs@PDg6cNmsxQdS@ApxAGCCsBrwy14vREoAbmpKfH1sEA2QCTtsgJThxg4gNNI4JNKJigsUxEhguNbIgNaA1lPG0imKPlIrhDyO/@UhloJNSdhryNf9GCLDHwtXkKkzwEir1/@mhpfmx0AfwE0VwTmW/BYQUAq7TNHHv0FcoYVXJEZTQLGEzALeAve@FcgGVbAtLCQJyzowmxCRGAoG7IbSEnYSzBYMR9YwoicRznU3zWHzlW5P73bQuEU118TqkhR4CQ41SVLq7l/08YIyVq7qJ3AqcPxrGpakDvl6Nrc6QNEQIFkqT1PnztRsSrwgGV4z9URmClNNXC@usZVE6dGO4QqxdkCRwFnD7UKgqpOLlDa@2IaMDlDqCm9anhMakVevgpBnmouike5aRdJmcgliGPjJkKpu0oA2trIOHrwCujL5suIQfWpeHYFlayeABRAymqYRusRL6uegGNdnePlAeb63dd5FBjN5zlSN1GY12tXM2F3mXZpj2wyTYAIGqKIkPsIwunN0HK8dQx9CjjDa2g3YENov4yDup6OGFazIXypoqQEoUXX8EoQNYXegGwocynR18dABsiF7JZyH9gy9IrLGQkltUyoqNGFgD@EoCJeIMt@ZU@Hs6cJXRybX/exKOTh7RjspksFVhIyJXfw9/QoNFOzlygnwdevcC0ruwHVCbAybuoXL1U@iVuhXUbKGF8xRldg6pYivRGgy/aFwlXW1qiW@FUgdAf2Z4qfSECicZHDDlkwSCcKyW3kpIg4JOjXkRpEqmnX0pIpRYxTw90bW3cU13XJPTFwY0EhrXVE3huqJo2XBZ9QDHZO6iDMORq@QfpNBJ2mrswbZZpGOTPhhM9pmtDm3BtEDGiJeNggBiCrCxAzQMDiHJJGMxfDop59gTEup5uGiPDO6IT9qaFsotIibeIVMv33Qd6s4jgxNCBIWcTDotBBifVF2OUNWDwT4GS01hBxBdZlTp6T9pexPbYth2QK10i0zkFJaz6ke8h2e64J3pTiICFOqDjuxuM80@OHxx0TnbPHjakietIptEFGtHTOyMQZk3oDhsuzBvOEB4A7hiWPTKgREGUby7Mp7btMeYBVw3udsUxYBDHowedR0d7T3effsvPHB3RjdHEVDGP1cQKQBjHKYW5NRrN7trAW1iTjTEBc3G8d/woiOXzZ4@OdjsPDk6OzyLRvJqYhipPpfHFYFOBPkcQIotZVvXHZm95OYeKqUuzCD6xQZmrRkA2JYIATwHdWKIolYnogSwyDo@CgLPAKs5zO0SRs5VKr6uWy3qxp@Xzpb7a7/Xyilwu9MsFpZCFR6lY0clbCi4I@pTO3ICJzYrgBBKmAZmnL1nMBxwOiKIacCyztfkKfW/JnFYo6KV8Ra1olUpFVUq9nKqUS7peLPXz2axelLP9blku527NXCQbyFotbCM6AwS9DicLqCcQvxS8lroDyzzwelekpyhKUSv0KzmlV8jme91KtlDudeWS2q3o2X4@JytyT1PkahAWZ1SBSgyhwZCrtIA1DbwEGTz5WDCYRpuYLjEGa9A@wUnkkMSMgzVkFBx8jzx6TPwVZJya9d0L6B6sH@MUje9eRPcRrh4vOFlqDR19wDIFxEVk0ekGjhV0DJePlxZWgVT69HOd/@ZAfszXcnaOkV/hAnSkfNeyTN0vvX5/yVmhzhcCDmXmwjlHndny8/LCr1/YG15rgcP48jQ@tmy9Nr4bXmuBw/gKLD5c7l4f3YrPOtAwsiKNDJfH18a14rEGMIypRGOKLqkv/MrUb9N6up/WWu@NgcK4KzRutlTeecVWKzr@SjliM@sgZ8CJPbKBf35k4Lx9f6nHxEIJvB3jgmmE5YmkhY@yWCYhwuX69R0uGhEjBoZ1YVPBOTR1sqJcwFjCKEYX5s2QfRA16GMJ9Eambvqw8WvU7dPHGgAcdFdn5qgHnfb0h34YalXpKX3hBOi6HCxP5S4l39X7E5CCpK5hofkDYEKlTCH73a6xCRRqAnceBO81YFXydAKSqCLmRTkQe3HpBGg2m4c9OzqmgF2VCnHL8/9kqfK9ieNBKP/937/dg0a42URDdUZlwdDQsfQrih/9jS3mB0ULfaxv3cWoTyuGmj4Upabikqtqhob1UdPWF4Sh6oxQ5PKbGxAUH4AJt@Aayzmbiwne6xOpElrJy@sMxDJGRFsDTWFXlkRYYlTINm21R6uBicKGTgM52NisGfQpEwojDA@MPJsSWrNyQRZbBbzhxJuwJ@4O@FAzGmO8b@uiPmS2oHZlHVhktWvotzS6o15MerYAnB4tMmasuAZ2UXo6WSf0TfWCGTtoXF98VkDHGAyAn/Dfm8CuhiDbUKFUuqKvD@GFa03csdCFxvKg41Ab7QqjW1JwTPbcBGL4m@dCw@ZaM0z6uEOjh8hF0QVYOlrRuJ9JiFSasVLNptqdoag@/HgswwQpgwM0p6Gl09kcDnvh2m90K9Lm8DhW0vCVyvrQbCcVq5J14pXEdlAJbAKZltnfU/WBhoWByxippqD0IsaNFD2YOl6Y1oDSeRtBM1UXUMvzm0O/hOajj9vQHUcmDcQuZ2G6BdkX2Qm2AGxaTfbJlt@rNds0XOza5iYKuroAt0gT97LRR2RK2lhXsT3KM7lDITStpwu25uFS7gZEuwOVY6uouE4dwRzR3lRpmn2F90bWYmhf6uy5fqB7szZXd6BYgklRwtDWjig97UOYituB6GN9PV6szZenmWvdl/tAMMURFdDuiNeuYdouOaXP26pl4EAw9lyP0dEaNFRLoOtBUfP6YH6mxkT0Z1k3tKtqDmyzWB5IKjw2Nv7E6eOY4L/vSv1C6iXLH6ZeAX9kW7L/3kj2LyTn4kNtR5cmHFy0jxhvGYHXkTB/UXJzAUGSwJ046wt3mC3TkKLE5OVNDeBowyt1Frx/jZFlU@0GI8t4RvltYP8wQKUMBs9hPPivk1r@9tR6dyNPN6ItfagQkca9MHUYyOjzRpMSJSt/ZAg5m707seqbE32ir6VVx91XOm5uv0UKuXumsn4xEv5sJ84I4VxnCPXGlx/vlGscw9F2K4FRTQM6@Qc5nbX0bgw8@hhF7hMwnKDhZsCBNRkvNe6SFGc9vb3mhuOgZ9u9pUyiz8dSpPKH@aklRt7V6X2rcMWEQVzbauSy2azP30Tmr5cstwlduTDsK4M9lxKmLouUF7A4G@JEjOvTWEylQtMbF66Ak5p3o07KphkBClypSJZh6d4Mn5uaZB217dq2@TFNCES3ZyD/BlwpLvx8qClv8Eb@bjCymPtwceak298068EGJF86hdpDwfs2bIhOvd6pmQVcsoZeOlix3j4PFJnI/VAqMMzTySW2dcLczHj6MyqyWBZLt/ZIxs7aXd1U2WtazN8WX0XM3RpfyLL4fDJd28L1MLYCtlhRja/QrfEMKsvogZAz1Ec6td4iHai9VxM3eG0Emtp4r/EW6XrjpnBjAwiFhc@l1bYIK@XZFohlnuoMdJRrTFwV9103EedgVn1t5R6N1IHODlXdRj0XUx24dZhJgwvj@kmPKtt1pkEwtvXjdlSAznShz9zgvTbCxzMN2nMy@vBU3Uq/1@hGpQ91dFFau5jwAV7RGtpDa6gP2U6g0LapewBGeuw43G2FgPz7u4wIpVHRnUrR2jVt07xL7SKNZBTTtvtr83WAB7V6EPSj4p2pXfDwXx@cBoTxnlYSHfg39Z2hPoFhy7U9e6wL1LYJ1MQJI/bcREmDBZ5fdybq1lkCqJHg/evG/0H5dKDa3nhMX52xOXHpgwYV6Pm6dU15SJO5C1YYHtt6xHBXH9hdbWh8KEtdXfUs40IKZoWY9VbpdhypBYMID9BZNA2oPGcmIjY0ov6n@Dra1KT@BBMbukLD@jaukv2J48ywJjzbJq5pXy1oxPIeinAql61AoGFTDvzVwTXelCPA3XXBLrJblkH8xcSNCEYZcWS6BT0LTIu8cVZpaYtnpHfkcuyxiTdaKT/NVGQN92OmRf2tD3SC0IjM3oL7Ev4sLUivHbCs4WTg3iR3bNK@B2wWPta29O4ADzWvNDRrVBiFVMt/bapvxZRwCze8O9ByE/3WFZbCrUssFE42BdU24NWBF7ThZOPUmWmMXfYkQl9ZyzTcXEa@CTVbLzr77dPT@2w9BE0f4vZGtoMHiYCtEDRHdzWcTkeKzHgoRn0sewCUWTDJAjiAXVuEmyvX65s/OuoJXz7RBypus3xk4I5Lcw1mQMyri9h3ifibE9U1vjmxPX1tnKuL2XeJ8rE6MLSHS60QRBjUrr8nj72WugA63WyIq6Hh0vMcgeGWOShEOIbCiHMd4P/XSW8r0/fhKenbp1kijJO/F5wIRyTYMx4acAEB/dW1aa2bmbfHVI6cUdNtk/KGR2dq/fdaDFu/KeC25K8mo/HE9V/rU6f7dqJT1qML6u5eGUAihddAmclQNb3109qRmVrgv/wBc2HcxJV/ZZj2gHxVzhJg12AARyZ9A9LtwfB9onrQO6w1iEzTv@PiKU6ECA4r3GvACz1HBMMyvNsnfTxPBbkpeGOB2OCDJxOlR/gU739sDMLZ@lp5dCtHA2P9TDPxoPzHSgeMDAMmntKD7GgMz9JHcd9PRt/3IwxGG0u/ispwty4EVXGIta2JJ@DO/9vGmOKtY0yVTMvFCHqQ1DcPHj/jAywZDDW2JfZDfKkOwuHENWcL08bNCGuQz7CAgdtMm2@GCKSMBzpVd/CUbuK8Q7jdMZ6uokPBA3udNHQyg5Hpo0QqGFwmowe6hquTd8rDE/sxsHcw3I2BGI@e6ri1YIXGbA6MQR/ZmmpCnfXulNwpjX7NWLIQxtWx3oW2Nxem9XzbpsgfqJ66gdeik41UYgxNH8Qlw@zqzis6ixgxbxKEb2bqoT6lostmhGI9VfA0jTHpOJ231I8i0nyVnI5tdur6FpwIyRAMHvRx9/V5EXc7L42Na8W5m@U8vmQbVPQeO@q3qaCO3rVN9sSRZgOxsAy2HUF1DN2VHhnWZErdiACc3nqhiG38zYolnBhxh9AFrwyQyMP9wLi9jW0udlfkLmCgL1WXbhJYLwEt7T2@@z6koepoNq62@YaPXGuLHCL7AJUPN1ezzQxdQKApkDtVmwSaCD6QVXPUHdHHZglmubWf6l08qNelp049dbqO3Vw@cOY7rhz5Cggddv8iSZ2AnMR/eKhbFfKWa90Y0wcl@VdrUSVI7omha29U/q69ic5ASyqVgdd2qOWtc8AMmbrgDXFnpuR5m0jGE@Ni0rstC/65BKpCJTxs72b8EzPgZjj@qVxXDPQBxenpItr0wT53EkeFABOUaT3bEQmFS6XUdJrnYywQ7jkYWAAWQFGFJqjsgOlKcQkwAR6FNfqk1SKJ62k1W5XnpEG4KkfOz1mseNGj9wfTMdVG8pQFbyXU80YiKQjJRLJtVUk2GYLrJjDAa8HVJdi@QV8sv4sqYJqKbKpmKCxxjSlzAJRDRSlD1eqZOnlm0YUg4FgcppKA6bs4ww2Ov/jDnq8/hupJGhkgoEKFoP4ne6QP7asdlq6fOozfKuqfwThAljGZNgRhf5cAI@1pQ6Y2xr4izw7Pyr4yCl/ZFFhO2NREmAvWuLhGggfrPNZ4LDfhISk/4TBUUCjgziYjCwhezxu6Ijk16Jm5ibPYBe@r4LI8BydBexlyRHo67iWjRyHpvL9p2xf0eATm5Bd/yFRw0AOR/kG1IHmqeieSIp57lKneC02zJ5DrIJI3umP7ICmsZJBeJrjKRjU/UXcejwlS3SCAkUKgGYMmw9Rj7O@eEuGAJFGnFJ5krxn9VGL36WdftLLnjXdkJOn//dsSf@1XHPepUCm6XIYEILU5IlbUuwDeC98k4RJTjiUYnhY1fJ7rirUH6sNiSIYHRgMcs@2x32uodiOqzCfERv@QfArNtJ0DFRkjqhiJIqx@RVVk0GNJFnJcVDGXCx0MrDyNmvW6RiI1YQs/wqlHCpAgqhlRwcRUKdHzk6juAYMkpuQtGSKSwbgtF7JgYxVpooaRUWMv2Gmci@4Alx7o3QndBXmpiEqhQYuT6DTqTWoClsBGTT@tF@2pkhXa09LBueQGldpuTz/NKl9CrdsOhLonYc87ePLgOiE2s2/fuuqMcNw8WWM71oFMJK5Pjk4OTs92z56dQivMA/JzyM6tBLQGsYgeRRvaJtWhBPWC7MBH0J/QhhoNUiShkjqq6OP5WPTQEAX165oTuAQzRkjTUugPBF8X3tUj/jcBfJrWN0iAUUcwDGAbArJhrWHhJ2PUBEX8sL42G4plBtJ47EBhxeC5gDW0lFYVRxpQWQJU1h2rimwu7A5zu0uNfTCW26ttZy0I1liYXiv0Z0VcWwXzv5Nyj2Gg/F8vN4vl9nJTmFvKDaChaxDmcPfo0bOnB8vBAMfom1LdRqXgn5ZjxBl7Gts@EqjvoYfU/YC4aNbgCEcDMKs/mDElgrp3pUOxfOKojVhgiqE0/1xsgZhQMw1UYnleY3WRStEcIA9Sw2KtHObrG9NIFoMxOhLdNStiSAQOuTDqIOMi58ccp8oYRbyCYmCsfnUFXe@EEnGfXifdKPuTCXocFg3H6InL@tyGoSocdVwC/8ioFJiUczIl/nAmnxOBKHCbujWAAgewfI2NUSTBKoJLsLxzYX5Rjx7kqfdKpfPUdJO6fwgORmlTHaPSLh/6ie3pVfJ6YtOD9gExCfkLqsJRZTovadMyZY70AD@w@cCdBuMWje/o8LSB3BljzSh9j@LcxMKBCoCYBkr/KKznoJpWdkaRqYJjVW77WseCoZJKb66vZSjkElxyabgGyB20EfrI45hAKbE0fsFRhSlVsUB2TRd4kh4M38CheDjUAnMi0pNT7PiUYBEuDjgphixjhnAxhHUbN7VQwVB6BZKV9pIFTlA4GrMbiTNZ3xIEqLkBiJv@KawqKjClQkuVeM4EN0Y1kzeCBFmoUpMw9EZmBHCNPr62Lr3/7d9jOvjaHpi/75un2T2w/aZv64P5twIfWQbbPw1tCth@wGwvJGyym4rH/OT9OZGNx8wAL@9zN8qENCFQ2krLErY2tvQXRyfE1VAdKLblCKTIRTMhhUGcA8kf8G8ESHFJ2xjBWQqLJlzEk2p9ASgCeAX4gewNcjQ0Pd05T6H6qaokYcZxtlqkm9P0KVssptqoXk9QCyMwYVKxUMzLEmRSuAwipAoyBnhWhkXI81WgibFLY9x4CRJ3vV4nnKuppt4o1hhuSAn1RY57GWY0AbAxJii0CISBIIsQ4Nf0g6USalrmMSgOZEk5iTStZzNUA24wRQ0AwqOzFRypB3bT9qsK8NjSpx7lmGaBAAQE27Ij6leDiASIiMWNugJXu@Pi/AtOoEQ6qBhtBu45gp0iWJVbh6ytF6Ttta1zX2ckAcT7yRrUtcD8j9YokmSYhSpDbmowTK3qH8TSkPunlo3zUIeQW5JSJCUnyUU@gqGcHxXkF7v6W4gSOjcQC003Xtljd3f/4Ojz45PTG5psKGRyFSxJks16ui2ImdZ5aEiG@V6u1L1D6fTx3mFQldFcLWaCEGKxGXA1m@tSW83phtSfs6NGN9OmHjcSkrN3jZjushEO6abam7EvfKUI4D476XAj1RR/PW@d15ttK34j@bfrtJPGxW1ELjC1XaqbNLmaTcxiqIb8DNWQu2JwjlbGQ7R4usqzLxZHcn2HiAcDD2IBChATpQBqDcYGGThm8zML3REK04PuUtLH5nCozsgwRxHIs0BjOnathaozX8fXUHWHptGNwdjdQ713TENHoIIi1O0humPT8FJ8jM5@NJADAiKW8vWmT6tTkS5vpaiGUhpXhtymNiyIj49BJ4D4kicTd0hO7DFZTD090APTU2BEyIMJW@/QyeeTEcD16eupjiRWB9ZEgMBQUckwq0yghp7law2bplEzG6TXQt1hfsHFUa@QmvLiUJ/2jAEQ8BSfgZ7@qQwcVXiuGQtNNYlZSaBxrIY/wxMm0Sr9KOVx00XkaksVDaunT1OoDaV6Dqwpuievnl8mee4GDlANdvuBzqsVVXZBR1Q9v0cs1MCtdLZKqCx9RddgpYIaZfCINjQLpHjqOY/ACONTqj9SxyQ1oToWXSISak21U1bG9RyeCE2mpsEi6TQVqOFFPYBhRtA@NVHEISlUSZySGtA66OpaPXy9McakJYviOZhpIjxJ4GTaPgzlOA3Fx0BAgiBVGm0D25ZUMUcMe0WGeRAG/WNU6RNBRYNrvKlqQFwShH4KdUFLTZr3IspyFj2Q1WqlUvVbY5nUVAigxU0qL0oQ7RoSEjCoUL/@iVuoNVSdjTrWHb1nAFm4/w3dsnSoIMCZkQpjsDoBJHP4TPChhMxC1TJNIc6y@NA/wgsZXVbBfJC8NnGlLSHV6LxMbQ5j6ss2Dqp9f1idSf@HJEq161TCbMwkYHT4ZioxbMjp3HY6nbC2UwkLh/p793A6Z54ATqIjgnQ0BSAhYfI1wGfgPBoJq5ZQ66lEr6Fs0xBgBfnsGgK8cyXxOqHOpcQ9GKkz4OKwzptKuFSLX1YU5TnkD3tIQsoAzlyj0jP6lQRMPmGk05gHMdHBDLyT2qdpSrPbpxKdOar5jKg0GPndbYWqhi1x4xsRrAJ9Z7@hgbArSNj9ndOdAHihgDm3zm8D78ES/gYeTiF0L5zuRjl/btnn7oTFp3dJqmCJ6UxkahShAqcpqES0ZlSeB2Lyq1/F5SLhUomdYs5OJwvZGjzkWoEUyKeJtpKPk/h9kNSlbc7hrtsPypdE7yvF14LQUvvi6/OTi5OTL/l2KhnfP37ByXkALZEKve96lYiy4SIfd8Xj21IsLm3L90qS9PLlS2B34Wo1xWYUSjznW0LyvJUqgaVZKm1niuXtzP1kh2aFTykKf0oMQyJtY@z2enDbQ/qtklScXWRnB9MCA/yJ7zaa9pnbIjMMxHcNwgZeH4CrXqqFOGmXVHU7nVfuWzVRySq/@PnWPHN90qn/4jsjSd/C1zG@vj9/jOZTufDp1tane3v5fAYqj5lPvjr51u7ubv5BpnDSKuzkhexW/S/@bGtLUeqKtHXuuvJ5snXxJadk85z4i58lT06@2XFdbD@8ckQGIz7LcMukUCAX5A1cF32Cf2p@04uYVTR3@29wgARmuUGJTTJZyCVPXySxuG/isizHZ/TXodWwReTmTul//PD4ddyLNxXpuQNvL/46XizHmREMYMsFtst4M15HsOI8PpMajQYYS//j30P45ucQD/rM6vBoFoK4irN4U2jQIG/jzSIYZEWBdP@fb387Fm9OERGaR4dEaSrbDFfk8j35XthG7bhczh/fB@fgos7T4KKCriwr7aA9I82NTRs6D6Hw0K7EjriF7R5gRpz42EANd4WDfMcP8PrL//SXP/rLH9Lfj@j93/BrN8Wt@y8fEKLDCIxXtXo/LJ1ESmXOtqGX18D2KHR/KgpwiZ3AXkOr4JcsXm5kOixXIQrHI4aVegifxK@S0P6RcLF4sAIttMh5pAm4JtKnIK@PLfKYXZYFf7gDK7qgA5gsssh0ULfxRZWGiZNVt6AxQgsJaAH5GLhY/B1U/nTNRZoLd0KLwHJNDY8jJVuUDdFhB64t@NE/XKEVn1vUxXemIDevLfLrX7F4K946P39o4a/7Gn@P3uDvtYe/Mw1/T1/j7@wN/p56@Dtx8fe4i78oLY/FBaAM6fRTYBl9pL3L9QxuUez4thB547H43@lFYiR@Ddd5WpjPW@KLdK3m/4GTqoU2vJgJ8nQ@F4T6i2Y63aJ5azX9TNaF8yZhWaZPsfOiDvGm6616w96nt9hpwiUk83ayaN8/f9Fs1Zfj8KO5fz@NnfY@xNNMnBPg4ZtNMq/Pm/NWfT6v1@Ffp8@5/wbXef3Gn74WV20DUHjNz5GAtltSsy21m@w6B7soNdFFlNpgaMK7A4CtVix@jehCWudU71NDaMnFwrlAaJfYrqKf5hJSlbeVnFSYflo8UGJxheOkbfR6iwMTsBeVWByZ9Arj1SvU4eX7r/9vvNvvv/63YIWs4ce10DcWbxACTE5iJ2tmL7PyhXwBBoNkgcccZodyD4l6VifZWXZGsiNb7oFJh18WTEa2T7IDkrWyliyDJxg8kvXQ1IfXAH59iMWBn5HNYuTZSwKpmDhUUL2n9P22Q/h2rEW4lzpwJ6KcFLNJsZhMGueF4vg1l0l22q3keS0uue22xPg2ouRrVOHtfE46nYMnDzodCVG5/dg@XvyPj0dR663/0bH9@Nge2fA/Pj5@DA2Xvp8W7sPVaKbr/msn3qzttKsC4mOAmXGpvtNu5gQ0F9OAZQq6pT/yWsQI7@ZWOwZC7fPnV7Xnz/F/dVm7qlFDaAVDpxYC@GDMAI7MASJ4XqtRA5rhuqSxUhsar563QxMzSM@vwOk5ATY7/EtLtr@Dv/H/r//jZyTVOuehH1zP6yl68fjj@ev59dx/NvlUyrek6vBDB7BjkOt5E40U6BpMrRR/zs/nzA2eKb7OImxiGvUmDbwAhE4fZ6m2k8BpgGCY8he02u1pNsvXuuASTm2rb@naCF@ju0YSXVzPAmFI3uYpSCFfq@V9c6lcq5V9s1ws1mrbIVQWLL4RgHRX1WrYm2rxMY95YH0slcU5M6pUPslVuXv3Uv5nCHbGY5Bu5Ur27dvQqdPpGU6ng@65t2@5Dof7RhqVAtiz5bdvoZ8neZB7n9j@imUFpFhZUhYpDFVX9Twn9cYYZzjcw@lyPFX7ms0iKIYmhXq9mG82i3kwF8s8X@MSbMtJapCuyPw8IXGsHCCPJuO@l1wu8dR1nkR/Eq@TnSbgu4sXuZ7HaXWTfIFPdWc6fw0ugZtcqTBHki@myumK/2ts8aS5Tfxfq9XKpfPbpe375@fnKwwL0qTatdqQ541rtYqTJfOa5msQx1366r17uQrUTjlba8c6nQe7Z7sd/PgYrgLDSEDQkVK3GK7wjZ1ki85sFSrnLSzReTuZrNbusxYuF0g8WfPhhCQQSlKu0ILHQXw2@nh0Z0pjXbm342Mil3IwxMTGdDdOKUt6uKDpELvf3wJHaBvSxbVnVzfNQOX6le2YvSujp2/F4iePdvcPzjJKHUYr5XB3P6OcPtuLy2gtLOzUO4f2pwe7D46fQYCTRwe7pwefHX1x8OwE3N3Yqzeqrqv6RNevOpPJ1WvUyq139DG4Lq6Orhmu@uqVOqYXqTG6dnX1/iffe/@T//P9T3/w/qffe//TH/3y6x99D@4/hPsH7P2Df1cp4POXX//TP3j/@z8Fx/8G93@F@@e//Pp3v81uav9TuP884van/h2BYzepxpvbeAEilJVyehsGju1KBZCButZjkNZv/vLrH/7sl1//1o/h/pf@/eOb92//fP39o@9uvjHcD//gdpgf/Hu4/4jFFcD@4PeZG75vwP8@g/utH7//nf/I/n/h/9D40/e/86f48C3/@Md/8efvv/OfFaX8F//m/fd@8P67P3z/3e@8/@7333/3Hyjvf/ffyNno4w/e/@iP/@ef/NH//JN/Qv9/SJ9/dJf/@x//47/6D3/1X/7qT/z753D/RzD9/K/@M6Dx3/zxT/D/wz/@m//6E/z/X//qb/74n//Nb/5ravg9Zvh//@W/Y8@//s73/vq7/@yvv/P1huf3bn1@fQf3r/83uNw9n3eJ5y7l@liXr3@t/Pyv1MYiFcABqh6dKMAb7s10kNpjWZL1H9AJf/SP3v/ubwBu/w5Agu0fgg3@zAJe36eWL79c8ktT2V5If/klCEtf@kLTl1Gg7xPyVgI@Nnv/LQB8SX3ZRUIoSPRfIBSAER8qAFtKnILgTkLm/Muv/9nP0D0Mia6/EY0vG7hGYBMI/DYo4vexM4fFiMJ@H8nB@598@/3P/sH7n/ze@5/8Jo4FQr6S2c0I8gcmFAGwcAc4BCzeBQ4AZRSYQLLdiilg2KrjBFhMTr98CY2wBSYQU7ZjhRzYYnKTmmU0Q0CQg7fZvFMaZ5zgnsbyFbDhTFQaBuE080qD114av4Objk0b4EdB8QO6BI3NMk4toEjdgHgxEAuT6ZSB9SfTPRoLhGykn5LOdmPKAqbRoUljIJghdHrKyQqXLjceQIKN6QOCcWHk6dhLeL9sNMuNaROje0ezAHGk9yBJgMLv86anzXdgb9A4AT42ffAOslJupNPNMrg0aFFpapkOTVMu0MLRsqcJLTe6E4K7@XbuE/IpJ5c5JvNDVRIfGp/pBfQOnfraAf92etsvDv0HRnpvY3hopymtH@bG/HfQmYb3ASBeQcBNYHALAubmPnhPWVRpmiy80iwGqLm0P2kYOlAGJR1L0/ZNUwukD3n4mKvOBmeMDouTSCTAVG9yOa5zDBIXcS6qrqc6uE5F@cUq4YoVDp1xUw3bKZg4oYLZ9oNteMrwP9iiu2NpSWrbsUQSBfYkCVIS0jk7b8dZIYISUts2LUCaApJPwQfv@/fBDDVE3wu3WHwRjokEdEkSePk84WMp@r0Xns4K6MgEkdhjd7BnT4Fvz3BcRi7iUgPP5gxi37Kr1cY7OV@KwZvaJ/ilGf@bJ9BY@L1dsV7HSm9eC3T6Ao3AGBZjzaa/pkrkWPP04AzAz46JrGRFAlz@db6k5Av5gpIrFgslRc4XK/lioZwDUlbMFhRFruTzlXKlNKdluQ/UIFPd7hbqzb934/r7f2/dtd4Vr1jzSzIV6RzsPNY0G2xLXwLXVrl2lqvRaRRac4lWNoM/JZeDJ@QxIxdK51tb5rWARW7TfWTXuHoN2YxdC1Oc8/0ELhL7JEY@ATe4IBFcXiL@hoCj45q/@Itfi2MLwJxcAOThY21AHhYdtOL19XXkjsW3vvrKI80mMPbC0WEsDkg/DL/PLhg9cSjSb7z1Jo5OfQeEPDj64uj06PiJ@ODoFJjtbxEllxVj8fl83g/n6KlVJ8fHxzGkNiA65WQMP9fIZDKhvl2wz6dqTFEEJSfkZEHO4f8DBgX/d4dX4K/gE0LllBiJjaNXDe4YIvI9INL3ZGYsFBfGLBrr/oneZowuBrYAic5j@Emg1nmsLoWeZ3jA@gk0BqCvRR7hdljPJmc223a5p2sbIPaH7OPW@44NstGvD7OnWhfM64HBTnSGXg9VVP3ojgxvuAHi2XiEx5B0539bDAejLmQQlwUYwB48HNO21wGUyLOTDaV8HCppwHV3qqUBwJ8effbwLPI@O9jdfxgrkr3jJw9WXgUfqEAeHRyehdYS8w2CFsIovnXw6NGq1X8BTaxRYXiLFEqZDAwt8MB3hl70LSZeBCCyeMs3WRJSs1xz9Hv35Ib8Tqh7CfKssfcu/WQyKucqcqUACAClHuggt9tGD8oeVz31xEm45OQRSvEoizeaqnk9J/kSSPSdLyYk14w9xp1/FZmdYDHc2EMQqUf4RR38epYXw3OfPfxqLk6FdPHztZMx2egIL3RCo2MMhkD/r@wAINZVVQL3x14QPipNQ03d6uCxNKjbDR9zDTguNxt9ko2JdKpWqZQL5UpOKWfKlXK@IBcLhYysZORSuVQBWpyVy3KxXKjImXK@ksvDYAG@hUopFgcaavQlCQZCmePgXYVoLQ2VwNdRm74tDpuxOJuAIm/wu@xxNbRPCKdDGA4/R@R6dF/zttHglDweOsjJBGJUiUbih4f72cNDjttDC05J72c5roeWQjmbLe1xnE599mFAUzjOZmHAC8A8Zslm9/Y5bsIiQBUSHDdEy0EROXSOM9Cyv3t4iOm8QouC4QHsgvkwixlYSgBmoSWXoyw@x70OowO4XZZQnub0AC2YJvocMp998OO4z4L8ZLMQw1MGx2J4GJR1d5fjjphldxd9PqcFL7CsfgMtu/TiOAcsgIQcNwDDwNF1i@O6YERU5DgNTNpMBTdUuI8qBSxP5bgZqyCsIo6bUmhVu@CAFfXdMZmHDx@qQ6@nD9g1c9hbg6yBjzGdHBx2P/usOxh0ndnuwWdP0efzzx@qr2YTpzvo@sG6HbhsCAM@F6PZ6gV5POp0VHOtzzfAx1rx6cw6Ouato76GPPnXABMZdT4Hn8/BZ90SJYsNrhGAdvHaG8F7T@1Sn@CiPvQ97Xa5GiKqNxvrOEeHfYZ@VjszUjXHrqF92thKppKZWauYPa9RZzJK8dfZ2hx9@yn6STckhvz1rDVtZM9BPCkp/sGIFNeeKgWDy2yNdoCqVbfUHVnJp6dV1Bdq95MkKcg7Kfne9pvUE35HyeWrXHtnR@Ba8vmOIperxdKL7QnH8VV87uRK1TepbDJLCD74Vul8p1SIhCiV0qqkVEslvjaHmvBgROpOPL3TSaWudPWC5zGvyDdB/tnXw2e0iEatn5pmpg2WKTLja9OGDNTZm8BIlL0RVw81KEzwu0ksxgFEN93JVpEmpzi5UuYgfUnikRYh9YD3y@fB4kf4ihiWjOwSSVVgn1yTy0VexF32HbvfoZ@dIS@jkMgux57jaRh6EjbYuUYFC7caO0Pumn6knaDuli5@5ZEePgbhjukBIWzuQi5VYrGmz1@esA9e1Hwr6lsQD/FzvrYj4mcovSUfpg0gcCKnM@ALRuLRsfjMctV@GMuZPvXEhzpuTdMCt312XFU8mOJ3zA3bql0Lz4U5PSONB1xR/QSMf2qjCSa1R1I0daLyV7RcnWaz0WmM9NHYm4EUQ@uiGQaG0ZTsEQaJZ2WC4wKdxh4UN1uzUEmTjtbEND6NNXuoVmKvsXc9qVYBdl7TG/RDxVwczxftWI0JLc@J7uDRlqPjRJ/oeIZEG75sHyDgPlTt9VxoOsSqhbk4cln9hKcVaIauMUO@R6eRndcGjRa6v8VHXeC4c0FovT2PNaFL1WZxteFOuuyzXdkuiD/F2hTc5FK@NiTdRvfFtOY0xsC0k5oJlRURRohao/BvTRgdO2KnMV0UO9doKTkFdyZllGwlo8gwJMJQCdBwl8Ceh1uGG/xlFFlSZoojhMtkp1lRzsi6nPHsAwtqOVutYmVDM1ErvFU@rWybqZ5N1LpAGw16aI1mUc0MydjIDFMQ6qmumgycF1LC651iOp/n@dpryJ2TSPXEPX4nX@ul9kiHBwcY2OFWSDFf6zdSL/haaotvuPrrWrTJU3ysiZ2clni8BZXry2HuZNTKkq2inLkWOsLcVF0vIZeUamuSaAkyFC/7dlDnvmpy51D3cwLSA4kumADTUAO3oEszNmPBKCzcxsglmjo0lVxRaj5IbOyTlxSXwu@2sp2PqWSypCSTfLKGEv8WuPvkidKSJBC25D15hwNGhatyFQXEuwhZupEFtnZWBMlrHusZ7pjkK7H4dWx@Pa9H99t9g8xmaloIrPcIGaQTMSLRhWCxEydb1CSITTots9vYHTzdrfnQu/uxeJVuUVpsMyFt/5SoIG197Opzut58wd5t3DkBqcao4pAWOfeX25UclLkXsUP53OsYq1W2oUCqp5tSO8ZxtKeytbdygWc5Je/iVGs32b8OvkhefYzCM0mpVdYDW@f8uyeGeV3OCU0q9KVI/F0aagR3WzWld3Eg6HNa0f5Wp@vr8fU1CLVzPPms5AqxuGUHu6BAlPSA0sFIUChwOAmik/Fp5UXpRfnF42fHz44Pyf1stVwtRwWC9v1MRk7KyTq5Dwyo8fQAhI23xC7I76zP6UaveC1eHSdz@WRuKVgjPm3kg1XTlNxsCnJdITuAq6QK9KYvF4Xs2yZDvCb1KCrg8/43fpyf1stgV4DJq0KdFtJKsylvK3x8/P7rf4sniq4Pvth9RJJYwL/9s58ppb/9s39FV/SS8xordCkOkGiUi6X4eZxlIV8iPFjosqAix5uS7y6XZD7uCswG2SvE3be@boeUki2D3/4xs3FFqLV4JR6Llx@/fEtIHaS@Zm8wMBRqkqQlSSpRBekJ/uQdThy9E7ZeAi1x3YQE4UkFgYPJju1ms7mN08Ik2UzjITilQCfZW/PaOZseQAli26I/3d3Gn/4idNh2XbAHNrBu13VSaMoERA5Jev8bv6soxb/9s99u8287bzvfBJJaqVSKshL/1c0r7mszUSAvusV2ZVbxOKlQZtvLkTq/ctkHlYOjdfRjusDb6o6KRxJReblpWBcQAMdzMONnGoEBqJI7nuOL@SPwGzxY4pu7qqsX84HNneGH1@k8HZ6rc6uSNDC84aRLD9KdObMj75geM5AAXwwQ0am5a9pdaaTi1AD9No8L4g9AoCrniSXBqIenBOi3C5HjRGUJHaowBorW6wBYB4uV4qsxAimP8cBve9rvc/SksG72TvWx6qDeEvAPjlMe9RAM1cbQc8jBEdglfig8/0prXCfJfbYXXKAHmW3Ke7jJ4PwbrVpClSzoeDqBw6O4/qkaus2bE9GGn6Plgi3eANG3UddkAM8@Nx4GCD9guwiBZUQ9ID4f0IiWiKRp@dNBJnAmlznQfCysfqILB5oQzY1DjIzqDKhaJBiXKe6koFlF1KHXkqvnGcYnNmRa3/TEtUHqDQKsN@oVoSXBCqXaBPuGA6yXXI5oHKGMFw0ZLUe64ecEAFmD4Alj1AeEm@bt7iuqA8dXfoD4JwZ@/qFzVDrEPt/uEcvXpEmuuoZHAWBoowAYUhrgcRRWRZklVO1OBrjPH/uCaDsDyXDdiV4olfM0QyqeGw5AgR9dAlUkX8WvRDOHx3TDUlS8ITH1S92kB@H9bKMuNZV1SopnuDUF1cQhg13kKepAVS6VFGohVckwtwcHh492zw4eZIggFxAcD1tpdgibilQu805T/745cYc@GmEQ1n3FbjHPkDzlZpL3pSTvZ/1@tNrT0QwHEeDXeHAeb5xKNmgwRx/hp49YxGSs9pBWZWgYK@mfJcdD3OzAkuFiViaOiXgTVG7Q8@NxDlEa04ojCi59fhvCYMF83gZsQHhuAG2kFVADPnXrgOAxRk0ZFHO5dYeugbAKQpOpAuD2TfwWWhIVL0WpbZL2HZUkz1AHs0cYadtKUrqAygaGjeSnbrKmAW8e8BTkMjXhr/0SGFYfc5FiFXdm782C9ktN/KMgHFQIDzwxH54N@cWfJ4HPCONzzZTHX1@qDnnTAAylPU5kRP3ApEfuUkmmjhOCvRGR5/CPYDW8Whiga/dmIuoSs3r7Q8Pspd5E0xgDq2n0U@m01mjk@GtI0hkDcXLHQAx1lNf4Grr1l9zCz4dL7bYF@RO3Lf2KfPn40UNo8qc6PWHdenG@nZAywNryNSyC2kgh0IPjxyeq4@oOL47xfRgKQSn8eoGfiAitPXJb2XOa@wyHRZOwFwLlHOieX3p3b3amDp6oIz2VVJPsbBMmZUCjGHVVZEJQzUineSii2jLOl@qowS03LsdfDxoUaujo/VoXKvqiNncbl6kBX/PgNYwmUYAkGopCY/cgUMOFx0qtG/gt44dnjx81knWVYKyNNb0ime6GyAGIQhGGHtredRx1toQ6QFUoVnnseCJFGLjSSa65XJa6pDaTwLJuzM8jm@pTEEUxuUDgXmqS8THOadxs0pqzwILZWG@gAxvaPjs44zIQ1pnoPDpaOLzNKNFiJ@8bQRoM3ZBS0CFwdoowjUb@3j3qxhRuNBpKNssDatbmEJsLmJsKxR6nNnfURi8VVqQ6Ntac8ldERVIt9wpVEAPLmy2UdmwHhohGD3jIey6QkAaq2b00vNk9F7CtEWgMuMeOPja28tvlY2Pvm19WTosPUlr3c5nLcK9c2wIRzRlHM@CoVyJji4DGOhrDLpoJVDaoqdJYvbClfC@rlbNludTTSwW9nM2VtYKeq3SBS9T6@XK3VymppYLWlWBw82gQcWTg13I4hv6YbP9uyW5izMog4/f7MnDrvUKlX1GyuVy@Wy70svl8vyyruVyxp5S7le7tXNsiPyhuBXQXx45VCvzpZuYudoO2@6H5/w8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._Vu 3>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Nikud code is on line 39: `ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ`.

In more readable form: `אֱאֶאַאֶאַאֶאָאֶאֲאַאָאֵ` (read right to left).

Explanation (top of stack is left):

```
          stack
push 1    [1]
dup       [1,1]
add       [2]
dup       [2,2]
add       [4]
dup       [4,4]
mul       [16]
dup       [16,16]
push -1   [-1,16,16]
add       [15,16]
mul       [240]
prn_num   []
```

---

**Triple Threat golf:**

```
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
```

Explanation:

```
Aliases:

A  22  Push a 1 onto Stack 2.
B  12  Pop the top number of Stack 1 and push it onto Stack 2.
C  23  Pop the top number of Stack 2 and push it onto Stack 3; if Stack 2 is empty, input an integer and push it onto Stack 3.
D  31  Pop the top number of Stack 3 and push two copies of it onto Stack 1.
E  13  Pop the top number of Stack 1 and increase the top number of Stack 3 by the popped number.
F  21  Pop the top number of Stack 2 and decrease the top number of Stack 1 by the popped number.
P  32  Pop the top number of Stack 3 and replace the top number of Stack 2 with the popped number; output the number replaced.

Program:

     A C D    E E D  E E D  E E D  E E D     B B C D     E E D  E E D  E E D  E E D       F A F       B P 
stk1     1,1                           16,16       16,16                          256,256     239,256
stk2     -                             -           16                             16          -
stk3     -                             -           -                              -           -

Duplicate top of stk1 with E E D until get to 256. Save 16 to stk2 halfway through to use it later in F A F: 256-16-1 == 239
```

Comment: This is amazing, I can't believe you're still going on this!

Answer (score 5):

## 242. [Oil Shell](https://www.oilshell.org/), 11250 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTBEQCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZJkEQLBNgAKJGtZtfMJDXXE7tynclc13h84zMziRM7SVV8UzfXk4pdrvJ8TbnyyT@gnS8pV8rzDyZr7Q2AIEWq1ROnKiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FjqaO/zVr@J4kRPbnA1M2yOe7nqk5xiXuiORvRm5rxluXs3GYgi16wwmI93y3EosThRCLP2KHFldowduxLMvdMt4ozvgpxIyduyBo42IN9Q8sBgQijzQzbejtx7p2qORZvVcgMwScqKBZ3/SvSBax/UcresZtgVeOUKeWaY26vQ0AhC6M3Z0j0afJxBF94KGWfYpEPLYdlwdk@/qrmujY5GQmj4ae7MGWEoAoTmG/Wj3yWcrgcuEfKZBzsamPl3Ji5Ihzw3d6a2EUBTyxdnh4aqrSr4h2hY5vJk/JUueOa5maqvx58juxLOPvFX3PNkd6JZGVKksqaueBbLnaDeCFImja72@YeqSYXWJSIa6OdYdgi6kbzvQZJ5uljKlTHt3EVLqYtjSwnMl2npwEc0ZuOBpX@pg1KElxobeI33HHhHNcq8gJaWcWcBjtOVldOhCBgHRyCsXQvd04lrGeKx7zBOKqzvUG1ImpmFdxBj2nTh2b9I1rAHA6VCv44lHy@TGuhCsQcY@DktoIHFaCwwMsnBqj/RoW7iAvJBrd6x3jb7RZZWjTz3dcqG8rkQMaLsrwzRJTzchwCL2bpq4Npm4EaeOqQ2lrhTDysVUyOjCJAbpjseEeUExIEuHmRLRR/Yrg7wBf3Pokul4RFxjBN5e1@73dZ280cdDCB7r2TECV3e8UqzQltABxtKhaPsn34JK87AurT7kq0c6ETjIBM0wLa5m2VB3DrG0EUOF7nhGiw7RhCH6ti2he8/WXSvpkSvbuSAdvathmTExVx/0tYkJKRp9bAtAAsMlIxve0IIWgWxBYA8rAuPGxGJrC4LJBG2rj6FXYtvaiCvQ0EETXzkaIIfj@o3oGSNADcNLukTXXAPJFQRxdatH0WIcEjIbShttcXJpQK@Dqpg4NG5Xdyje03gJlgKi1EJE5a8cwwN0wFLskhNdc8iZo@sCQ1Ld7WpjRNFokpCYjSl4WBCJYmWtljw4PkwCdrIQkjYGbHSyZ9/8PKYRqU4S7SrcdY6rxg6ePCDXiRaaGcEEDB47vCaQ@jviyq2WDvdU6cgDZx6DWGNQKyaR7bEna@IYMih6kEFZQyOaxEtVGpuRhEltpQ0ifYZB9aA1gAKQL9K0ZN2J4yBpX1SqdgGFNm1rAPUJhXUmFmvyQgaaAPCv56aJfqkjDrA2sq9oDZ8NAUPgD6ARssJGG1qhMN5AP/RrNEjXtc0JhYOQroedEWoFgmKMR33yBelrholBwB@jYrl2dBeQE8NMrB62/Miw9J5EgmxQkuNAR7yE5DSIlDpAbxhFCAvNFABDQ9i0qOj1/rd/rzcYQDy73a7t9Hx0/QKQvUvHRY1mFkY2gghrW5pJswVwaUydBYcELjXT6FESp1kzPwmaCZrqlT0xe4R21CsDutxQA0qrA3XoejpDcnviQR7TZKRdMHJoMMyFgo@0DjQsTYCmTYstkvv70Epd6OYUZ8TRxOuXiDg@IElXfsHvVPidrZYOmRMkYTshy4MqIJy0TZ3AlrwNc77YXRonXE9zbaMXG8@8oW2pROwSrlu3x7rFJ5fiSKaTTicpSEimeaFq1LtS37B6fLIGuNiAhJNCtVvvNo3KeXUleDRJiOYKo8HuqvNdgUNSQzvFpTwCzkICSvaF6JsifrbbxipHbynijBWz6nbJHOKUb0G8tBFBgA5JrqnrYz4jKQKSCYRbW270WFfSlTj8AleM81QynkxFi05jgJIuFRQ765lhI9kyx0NkNqBSLHcMNNdB3O1qgD0ujmge8HNp0qF4TYdBoCyUJl7pSaDaHSCkAR7RLsm6HIYXkVD6MSy60HJP1nuRjgxEAPqy596gxqaNrAHNE448QDosTFQbQNNAYFaQXVYQlhJ1WS7ShQUEBWPr6KQkdgzoBNjdgKb7OB8pG4BnVQYDsbFOEqE9I22GoxrjCxYdBsc0jYyAPDgz0tWR5gDx0dmAgolMaP9zgekldp9kRDWfX@5jN7qY58i74ldApN/It/YkLHy0MyGhIX3gsU3NGky0AdAL24IgWrerjz2fUEFJXA9I0ep4Qx1Ff/CU3GEscX81bTqIBLzRIg0k8qz1/KFQQ@ri8@wiMGTI9zFBgPQMB8gSjOQrqQPA5Uri3EsEWcrAS25DFgIOAJBMn@rdiQdUDRD4amh0h4CzmDuL0UU2CK0mD07R1IGyi/0wacyM0rinxiQ5dMJsbIxCxBa9GQ8MrhhVY8mBNn7U4faYNXe0JmI7zCIMBBFXSdYkwL0PxDmyLXtNpFCRYbQIsuzD2gE4sVPkiGHgCtgu2llDNjlsImgzoBrQ8wH/hp43diswThjecNKRAFPkM2d25B1biCyy58wMz2bmjml3gCy70D/lIAW5O@kY05UCUbewDV@5sUtgwPouqcPI/XoCWMcn@y4QTOq@j8ARL44SbhoFe3IASIEkqCi@71JSfAhE5XRmdXluCSm5NOGw73ICGDBgWDWfI/O2nM1X4LSaSwSLZkaSEUp2nS41iBGeFKNHcJqt2CdLRbtjHmOfcBw8@prp6vC2JqaJ1onFqBzPeAWBXMc@@QRIG0@TM0Zj0@gaXpv5knv3fJ6CbIGAh2xTH3kmAcJ84kvSEhAUgPGHHwYtefYpZXZ5AQryyXwpYd1xbIel6w0d@4pQBwSLRSt13x4hdSfPKcOFHDTItIaFsr0/ltKhVFvLQoRjKuWXk0nplW1Y/HVya2srWUk2YMTc2toBUw1NO2hKgWmHmkRqQjgJTTREmprQt0lDoNt5ct4MYp4K59gdpjjavzHGvNasVLLnaa2p@G8V3wLUM4wYAC3iC@JJCvU6GgWBa1xBQaVOf7n0@zjqnXYdY@xXwufapcbsfi1kaTVAw9kOCgZVZF5ur5NR3QHuAoSB7pB3kq1mpnXeum71Uq15Mo2hhapW70ChID1@JA0cewJsiNDMVUTlXBCaWWA@OvVkJrnN8yURxDiQRIRPS0JKY7XNJ3UYDflWKwmV6tdPszt0aHzTtCoIYVVBPpDhAV6bT0rXJUi/I5wLqSSEFZJpEN3qySTUTBcrwaWFxr60VEHHT7/BKmY/lYrR7g1SKd43hlNwQ6F3OfjJ5M0bpF0sjk6IYeZEY1ze2AeQj6wAVkLPFaE18Or0CdLRpTQ@s/tMKtrHx8Gjw5g@pa312fHhwdM6TWaouRfAU4gDhJWBV4ZacXoSUANz0tNj62CAbICpu8gJThxg4oNul4g2oWBil2UiMlx0yYbYgNZQxtMmojlaLoI7hPzuL5WBRkLdacjb@JdukCUGvjZPYZKHQLH3Tx8tzY@NLoCfIF3XROZbdFgBwCpvM8cefYUyRoUcURnNAgYTcAv4y144F2DZloi0MBDn7GhCbEIEIKgbclvISRhLMBhx35iCSBzH@RSf9UeOFbn/fdsC4VSXnlNqyBEg5DhVpUtr@f8TxkhJXXfRO4HTB@PY1LpA75eja3GkBRECBZLl9T5C9UbEq8IBleM/VEZgpbqahfXXM6icOjHcIVYvyBI4Cjh9qFUUUnFyh9baEekClzuAmtanhsekVujhpxjkoebyAspJu0zOQCxDHhkzFUzbUQbW7oKErwOvjL5suoQcWJeGY1tYydIBRA2kqIptsBL5uuoFNNrdPVIfbK7fdZFDjd1wViJ1G411tXK7LvQuyzbtgU22AQBRU5IYYh9ZOL0JUo6njaFHGW9oBe0ObBD1l3FQ18MJ00I2lDc1hJQpvPQKRgGyvtALgA1lPj366gDYECWfyUD@A1uGXmEhI7GslhEdu2QB4C8BmIg32JJf6ePhzFlCJ9f25008OnlIOyabydKAhYRc@T38DQ0a7eTMBfp54NULTOvKfkBlApy8i8rVS6Vf4lZYt4ESxlec0TWoiqVIbzT4on2RcLXkJboVThWI/ZHtafIXEpBofMSQQxYNwrlycispiyI@OepF1AaRe/qljFRqEfP0QO@ujXuq610ZfXFwI4FhbfUEnhuqpgWXRR9QTPYO6iAMuVr@QSqFhJ3mLkybZRoG@bPhRI/p3aFNuBaIGNGScTBADEFWFqHmgQFEuSQM5i8HxTx7AmJdTzeNkeEd0Ql700LZRaLEW0Kq5fvuA71ZRHBi6MCQswmHxSCDk@qLMcoaMPinQMlprCDiS6xKHb0nby9ie2zbDsiVLlHonIIaVv3I95Btd9yTvClEwEId0PHdDcb5J8cPDtonu2cP6/LEdWTT6ACN6OntEQizJnSHDRfmDWcIDwB3DMseGVCiIMo3F@ZT2/YY84CrBne74hgwiOPRg/ajo72nu0@/5WeOjujGaGJqmMdKYgUgjOOUwtwaTdfu2MBbWJONMQFzcbx3/CiI5fNnj4522w8OTo7PItG8mpiGpkzl8cVgU4E@RxCiSBlW9cdmb3k5h4qpS7MIPrFBmatKQDYloghPEd1YoiiVSeiBLDIOj6KIs8AaznM7RFUy5XKvo5VKeqHXzeWKfa3f6@VUpZTvl/JqPgOPYqGsk7cUXBT1KZ25ARObFcEJJEwDMk9fipQLOBwQRbvAsczW5iv0vSVz3XxeL@bKWrlbLpc1tdjLamqpqOuFYj@XyegFJdPvlJRS9tbMRbKBrNXCNqIzQNDrcLKAegLx4@G11B1Y5oHXuyI9VVUL3Xy/nFV7@Uyu1yln8qVeRylqnbKe6eeyiqr0uqpSCcLijCpQiSE0GHKVFrCmgZeogKcQCwbTaBPTJcZgDdonOIkskphxsIaMgoPvkUOPib@CjFOzvnse3YP1Y5yi8d0L6D7C1eMFJ0utoaMPWKKAuIgsOZ3AsYyO4fLx0sIqkEqffq7z3xzIj/laycwx8itcgI6U71pRqPul1@8vOavU@ULEocxcOGepM1t@Xl749Qt7w2stcBhfjsbHlq3XxnfDay1wGF@exYfL3eujW/FZBxpGVqCR4fL42rhWPNYAhjEVaUzRJfWFX4n6bVpP99Na670xUBh3mcbNlsrbr9hqRdtfKUdsZh3kDDixRzbwz48MnLfvL/WYWCiBt2JcMI2wPJG08FEXyyREvFy/vsNFI2LEwLAubCo4h6Z2RlLyGEsYxejCvBmyD6IGfSyB3sjUTR82fo06ffpYA4CD7urMHPWg057@0A9DrSY/pS@cAF2Xg@Wp3KXkO3p/AlKQ3DEsNH8ATCyXKGS/0zE2gUJN4M6D4L0GrEKeTkASVaWcpARiLy6dAM1m87BnR8cUsKNRIW55/p8sVb43cTwI5b//87d70Ag3m2iozagsGBraln5F8aO/scX8oGihj/Wtuxj1acVQ04ei7Gq45KqZoWF91LT1RXGoOSMUufzmBgTFB2DCLbjGcs7mYoL3@kQqhFby8joDsYwR6a6BprArSyIsMSpkm7bWo9XARGFDp4EcbGzWDPqUCYURhgdGnk0JrVm5IIutAt5w4k3YE3cHfKgZjTHet3VRHzKT1zqKDiyy1jH0Wxrd0S4mPVsETo8WGTNWWAO7KD2drBP7pnbBjG00ri8@K6BjDAbAT/jvTWBXQ5BtqFAqX9HXh/DCtSbuWOxAY3nQcaiNdoXRLSk4JntuAjH8zXOhYXOtGSZ93KHRQ@Si6AIsHa1o3M8kRirNWKlmU@vMUFQffjyWYYKUwQGaU@@mUpksDnvh2m90K9Lm8DhW0vDl8vrQbCcVq5J14pXMdlCJbAKZltnfU/WBhoWByxhppqj2IsaNFD2YOl6Y1oDSeRuxa2ouoJbnN4d@Cc1HH7ehO45MXRC7nIXpFmRfZCfYArBpNdknW36v7tqm4WLXNjdR0NUFuEWauJeNPiJT0sa6iu1RnskdiqFpPV2wux4u5W5AtDtQObaKiuvUEcyR7E2V1rWv8N7IWgztS5091w90b9bm6g4USzQpShjdtSNKr/shTMXtQPSxvh4v1ubL65pr3Zf7QDDFERXQ7ojXrmHaLjmlz9uqZeBAMPZcj9HRGjQ0S6TrQVHz@mB@psZE8mdZN7SrZg5ss1AayBo8Njb@xOnjmOC/70r9QuqlKB@mXgF/ZFuK/95I9i9k5@JDbUeXJhxctI8YbxmB15Ewf1FycwFBksCdOOsLd5gp0ZCSzOTlTQ3gdIdX2ix4/xojy6baDUaW8Yzy28D@YYByCQyew3jwXye13O2p9e5Gnm5EW/xQISKNe2HqMJDR540mJWpG@cgQSiZzd2LVNyf6RF9Lq447r3Tc3H6LFHL3TGX8YiT82U6cEcK5zhDqjS8/3inXOIaj7VYCo5kGdPIPcjpr6d0YePQxitwnYDhBw82AA2syXmrcJSnOenp7zQ3HQc@2e0uZRJ@PpUilD/NTS4y8q9P7VuGKCYO4tlXPZjIZn7@JzF8vWW4TurJh2FcGey4lTF0WKS9gcTbEiRjXp7GYSoWmNy5cESc170ad1E0zAhS4XJYtw9K9GT43Nck6atuxbfNjmhCIbs9A/g24Ulz4@VBT3uCN/N1gZDH34eLMSae/adaDDUi@dAq1h4L3bdgQnXq9UzOLuGQNvXSwYr19HigykfuhVGCYp5NLbOuEuZnx9GdUFKkkFW/tkYydtTu6qbHXtJC7Lb6ylL01vpBl8flkuraF62FsBWyxohpfoVvjGVSW0QMhZ6iPdGq9RTrQeq8mbvDaCDS18V7jLdH1xk3hxgYQCgufS6ttEVbKsy0QyzzNGego15i4Ku67biLOwaz62so9GmkDnR2quo16LqY6cOswkwYXxvWTHhW266wLwdjWj9tRATrThT5zg/faCB/PutCek9GHp@pW@n2XblT6UEeX5LWLCR/gFa2hPbSG@pDtBAptm7oHYKTHjsPdVgjIv7/LiFAaFd2pFK1d0zbNu9Qu0khGMW27vzZfB3hQqwdBPyremdYBD//1wWlAGO9pJdGBf1PfGeoTGLZc27PHukhtm0BNnDBiz02UNFjg@XVnom6dJYAaCd6/bvwflE8Hmu2Nx/TVHpsTlz5oUJGer1vXlIc0mbtgheGxrUcMd/WB3ekOjQ9lqaNrnmVcyMGsELPeKt2OI7VgEPEBOkumAZXnzCTEhnrU/xRfR5ua1J9gYkNXaFjfxhWyP3GcGdaEZ9vENe2rBY1Y3kMRTuWyFQg0bMqBvzq4xptyBLi7LthFdssyiL@YuBHBKCOOTLeoZ4BpUTbOKi1t8Yz0jmyWPTbxRivlp5mKrOF@zLSov/WBThAakdlbcF/Cn6UF6bUDljWcDNyb5I5N2veAzcLH2pbeHeCh5pWGZo0Ko5Bm@a9N9a2aMm7hhncbWm6i37rCkr91iYXCKaao2Qa82vCCNpxsnDozjbHLnkTsq2uZhpvLyDehZutFZ799enqfrYeg6UPc3sh28CARsBVi19HdLk6nI0VmPBSjPpY9AMosmmQBHMCuLcLNlev1zR8d9cQvn@gDDbdZPjJwx6W5BjMg5tVF7LtE/M2J5hrfnNievjbO1cXsu0T5WBsY3YdLrRBEGNSuvyePvZa6ADrdbIiroeHS8xyB4ZY5KEQ4hsKIc23g/9dJbyvT9@Ep6dunWSKMk78XnIhHJNgzHhpwAQH9tbVprZuZt8dUjpxR022T8oZHZ2r991oMW78p4Lbkryaj8cT1X@tTp/t2olPWowvq7l4ZQCLF10CZyVAzvfXT2pGZWuC//AFzYdzElX9lmPaAfFXKEGDXYABHJn0D0u3B8H2iedA7rDWITNO/4@IpToSIDivca8ALPUtEwzK82yd9PE8DuSl4Y4HY4IMnE@VH@JTuf2wM4tn6Wnl0K0cDY/2sa@JB@Y@VDhgZBkw8pQfZ0RiepY/ivp@Mvu9HGIw2ln4VleFuXQiq4BBrWxNPxJ3/t40xhVvHmAqZlgoR9CD8Nw8ePxMCLBkMu2xL7If4Uh2Ew4lrzhamjZsR1iCfYQEDt5k23wwRSBkPdKru4CndxHmHcLtjPF1Fh4IH9jpp6GQGI9NHiVQwuExGD/Qurk7eKQ9P7MfA3sFwNwZiPHqq49aCFRqzOTAGfWR3NRPqrHen5E5p9GvGkoUwro31DrS9uTCt59s2Rf5A87QNvBadbKQSY2j6IC4ZZkd3XtFZxIh5kyB8M1MP9SkVXTYjFOupotftMiYdp/OW@lFEmq@Q07HNTl3fghMhGYLBgz7uvj4v4W7npbFxrTh3s5zHl2yDit5jR/02FdTRO7bJnjjSbCAWlsG2I2iOobvyI8OaTKkbEYHTWy8UsY2/GamIEyPuELrglQESebgfGLe3sc3F7orcBQz0pebSTQLrJaClvcd334c01JyujattvuEj19oih8g@QOXDzdVsM0MHEGgK5E7rTgJNBB/IqjnqjOhjswSz3NpP9Q4e1OvQU6eeNl3Hbi4fOPMdV458BYQOu3@B8CcgJwkfHupWhbzlWjfG9EFJ/tVaVAmSe2Lo3TeacNfeRGegZY3KwGs71PLWOWCGTF30hrgzU/a8TSTjiXEx6d1hhSxYdpmMdFzpXl7v2YhYtjukWGGvk6P8Ew9UOUt4jN9N@2dxwM1w/PO@rhRoGorTc0sUqYId9CSOqgYmKC17tiMRCsfzWiolCDEWCHczDCwAC6CoqhRUo8C0sLgE2AuPwhp90mySxPW0kqkoc1InXIUj5@csVrzoof6D6ZjqOXnKgjcT2nk9kRTFZCLZsiokkwzBdRNY67Xg2hJs36Avlt9FFTAdSDZVYBSWuMrURAAyowqWoWb1TJ08s@gSE/BCDlN2wDRpnOHWyV/8Yc/XTEM1MI0MEH2hQlCzlD3Sh/bVDkvXTx04Aw0122AcICWZTM@CuL9LgEX3ukOmkMa@Is8Oz0q@mgtfjRVYTtikR5gL1ri4@oJH9jzWeCw34fErP@EwVFAo4PsmIwtIac8buhI5NehpvImz2F/vK/eyPAenV3tpckR6Ou5So4cs6YqCadsX9OAF5uQXf8iUe9Cjlv4RuCB5qtQnkiKeqFSoRo1u155AroNI3uiO7YPwWMkgF01w/Y7qlKLuAh5ApFpHACPFQOcGTYYp3tjfPSXiAUmitio8I181@nxi9@lnXzQz5/V3ZCTr//nbsnDtVxz3qVguuFyaBCDVOSJW1DsP3gvfJOESU44lGJ5DNXxu7oq1B2raYkiGR1EDHLPtsd9rqN4kqiYoxEb/@D2PZtrOgfKNEVW5RBFWv6LKN@iBJwt5Oaryy4UOBlaBRs16XT3BT9iSknjqkTwkiApMNDAxJU30ZCYqksAgiSl5S4aIZMARKPkM2FhFmqi7ZFTfC/YwZ6N7y@UHemdC91deqpKar9PiJNr1WoOagNmwUYdQ80VrqmbE1rR4cC67QaW2WtNPM@qXUOu2A6HuydjzDp48uE5Ijczbt642Ixw3T1bZXnggE4nrk6OTg9Oz3bNnp9AK84D8HLITMQGtQSyih9yGtkm1M0G9IKPxEfQntKGuBJ4kNFJD5X@CEIseR6Kgfl1zIpdgxghpWgr9geDrwrt6xP8mgE/T@gYJMOoIBhhsQ0A2rDUs/GSMOqaIH9bXk0OxzEAajx0orBg8cbCGltKq4kgdKkuEyrpjVZHNhd1hbnepsQ/Gcnu17awFwRoL02uG/qyIa6tg/ndS7jEMlP/z5Wax3F5uCnNLuQE0dA3CHO4ePXr29GA5GOAYfVOqWy/n/XN4jDhjT2OMSqAYiB5/9wPiclydIxwNwKz@YMbUE@relQ7F8oljd8QCUwyl@ediC8SEmqmjeszzKqsLnqc5QB6kisVaOSbYN6aRLAZjdCS6a1bEkAgccmHUQcYlzo85TtU8SngFxcBY/eoKut4JJeI@vU66UfYnHfQ4LBqO0ROX9bkNQ1U46rgE/pFRKTCp52RK/OFMOSciUeE2dWsABQ5ghSobo0iCVQSXYHnnwvyihj7IU@@VRmfA6fZ3/3gdjNKmNkZ1YD70E9vTK@T1xKZH@ANiEvIXVDmkxrRp0qZlaiKpagAQIIDvDcYtGt/R4WkduTPGmlH6HsW5iYUDFQAx3Zb@IVvPQQWw7PQjUzLHqtz29ZkFQyWVC11ff1HIJbjk0nANkGhoI/SRxzGBUmJp/IKjclSqvIHsmi7wJD0YvoFD8XCoBeZEomey2MEs0SJcHHBSClnGNOFiCOvWb@q3gqH0CmS27ksWOEHhaMxuJM5kbUsUoeYGIMj657sqqBqVikMV4jkT3HLVSN4IEmShQk3i0BuZEcA1mv5auvz@t3@PafdreWD@vm@eZvbA9pu@rQ/m3wp8FAVs/yS0qWD7AbO9kLHJbqo085P3Z1s2HmADvLzP3SgT0oRAHSwtS9ja2NJfHJ0Qt4uKRrEtRyCfLpoJKQzinGFBfRkjQIpL2sYIzlJYNOEiHr75BaAI4BXgB7I3yNHQ9HTnnEfFVhVZxozjPLhEt73pU7YMTfVcvZ6gfkdgwuRCvpBTZMikeBlESFVvDPAUDotQECpAE2OXxrj@EmT5Wq1GOLermXq9UGW4ISe0F1nuZZjRBMDGmKDQJBAGgixCgF/DD8YntJQiYFAcyJJKEmlaz2aoBtwgTw0AIqCzFRzWB3bT9qsK8NjSpx7lmGaBAAQE27Ijil2DiESIiMWNWghXu@PiZA1OzUQ6qBRtBu45gp0iWIVbh6zNF6TltaxzXxslAcT7yRrUtcD8j9aoqGSYhcpIbupG5Fc1G2JpyP1Ty8YZrkPILeFVWc3KSkGIYCjnRwX5xa7@FqKEzg3Eoqsbr@yxu7t/cPT58cnpDR05FDK5CpYkyUYt1RKldPM8NCTDfC9X6t6hfPp47zCoymiuFnNMCLHYZriazXWpreZ0Q@rP2SGmm2lTjxsJKZm7Rkz374iHdLvuzdgXvnIEcJ@dobiRKi9cz5vntUbLit9I/u06vadxaRuRC0wtl2o9Ta5mE7MYKjg/QwXnrhSc0FXweC6e2/Lsi8VhX98h4sHAg1iAAsQkOYBag7FBBo7Z/MxCK4XKNKy7lPSxORyqjTLMUQTyLNDFjl1roUTN1x421NyhaXRiMHb3UKMe0/0RKLcItYZI7tg0PF6I0dmPOnJAQMR4XyP7tDKV6MIZT3Wf0rjS5DaFZEF8Qgw6AcSXPJm4Q3Jij8li6umBHpieAiNCHkzYSopOPp@MAK5PX091JLE6sCYiBIaKSoZZZQI19CxfH9k0hTrfIL0maiXzCy6Nenl@KkhDfdozBkDAeSENPf1TBTiq8MQ0FprqKLOSQONYDX@GZ1eiVfpRaummi8i1piYZVk@f8qhnpXIOrCm6J6@eXyYF7gYOUN14@4E2rRUleUFH1Dy/RywUzK10tnKohn1Fi2G5jLpq8PA3NAukeOo5j8AI4xPfH2ljwk@o9kaXSIRa@RZvpV3PEYjYYAogLJJKUYEaXtQDGGYE7VMTRRzCo7JjXq5D66Cra/Xw9cYYk6YiSedgpokIJIGTafswlOM0lBADAQmCVGi0dWxbUsEcMeyVGOZBGPSPUXVSBFUYrvGmSgdxsRH6KdQFLTVp3Iuo4Vn0QFar5XLFb41lUlMmgBY3qbwkQ7RrSEjAoEL9@md5odZQKTdqb3f0ngFk4f43dMvSoYIAZ0YajMHaBJDMEdLBJxjSCyXONIU4y@JD/3AwZHRZufNB8trENbyEXKXzMtU5jKkvWzio9v1hdSb/fVmSq9d8wqzPZGB0hAafGNaVVHY7lUpY23zCwqH@3j2czpkngJNoSyAdTQFITJhCFfAZOI96wqomtBqf6NXVbRoCrCCfXUOAd64sXSe0uZy4ByN1Glwc1nn5hEv1A2YkSZlD/rCHJOQ04Mw1qlOj31/A5BNGKoV5kBJtzMA7uXWaojS7dSrTmaOqz4jKg5Hf3VaoatgSN74@wSrQd/YbGgi7ioTd35PdDoAXqp2z6/w28B4s4W/gsRdCd9npbpTz55Z97k5YfHqXpKqbmDZGpqARKnDKQyWiNa0JAhCTX/0qrhQIxyd2Clk7lcxnqvBQqnmSJ58mWmouTuL3QVKXtzmHu249KF0Sva8WXotiU@tLr89PLk5OvhRafDK@f/yCU3IAWiRlet/1KhJ1w0U@7orHt@VYXN5W7hVl@eXLl8DuwtVsSI0olHQuNMXkeZMvgqVRLG6nC6Xt9P1km2ZF4FVVOCWGIZOWMXZ7PbjtIf0KCh9nF9nZwbTAAH/iu42mfea2yAwD8V2DsIHXB@Aql1o@TlpFTdtO5dT7VlVSM@ovfr41T1@ftGu/@M5I1rfwdYyv788fo/lUyX@6tfXp3l4ul4bKY@aTr06@tbu7m3uQzp808zs5MbNV@4s/29pS1Zoqb527rnKebF58yamZHCf94mfJk5Nvtl0X2w@vLFHAiM8S3ArJ58kFeQPXRZ/gn5rf9CJmDc2d/hscIIFZrlNik0zms8nTF0ks7pu4oijxGf21aTVsEaWxU/wvPzx@HffiDVV@7sDbi7@OF0pxZgQD2LKB7TLeiNcQrDCPz@R6vQ7G4n/5dxC@8TnEgz6zGjwa@SCuwizeEOs0yNt4owAGRVUh3f/27W/H4o0pIkLj6JCoDXWb4YpSuqfcC9uoFVdKueP74Bxc1HkaXFTQVRS1FbRnpLmxaUPnIRQe2pXYEbew3QPMiBMfG6jhrnCQ7/gBXn/5//3lj/7yh/T3I3r/J/yOTmHr/ssHhOgwAuNVqdwPSyeTYomzbejlVbA9Ct2fSiJcUjuwV9Eq@iWLl@rpNstViMLxiGGlHsIn8asktH8kXCwerG2LTXIeaQKugfQpyOtjizxml2XBH@7Aii7oACaLLDId1G18UaVh4mTVLWiM0EICWkA@Bi4WfweVP11zkcbCndAisFxTw@NIyRZlQ3TYgWsLfvQPV2jF5xZ18Z0pyM1ri/z6VyzejDfPzx9a@Ou8xt@jN/h77eHvrIu/p6/xd/YGf089/J24@HvcwV@UlsfiIlCGVOopsIw@0t7lega3JLV9W4i88Vj87/QiMRK/hus8Jc7nTelFqlr1/8BJVUMbXswEeTqfi2LtRSOVatK8NRt@JmvieYOwLNOn1H5Rg3hTtWatbu/TW2o34BKTOTtZsO@fv2g0a8tx@NHcv5/CTnsf4mkkzgnw8I0GmdfmjXmzNp/XavCv0efcf4PrvHbjT1@Lq7oBKLzm50hAW0250ZJbDXadg12SG@giyS0wNODdBsBmMxa/RnQhzXOqUaouNpVC/lwktEtsV9Cv6xJSUbbVrJyfflo4UGNxlePkbfR6iwMTsBflWByZ9DLj1cvU4eX7r/813q33X/8bsELW8LNd6BuL1wkBJiexkzEzlxnlQrkAg0EywGMOM0Olh0Q9o5PMLDMjmZGt9MCkwy8DJiPTJ5kByVgZS1HAEwweyXho6sNrAL8@xOLAz8hkMPLMJYFUTBwqqEZV@n7bJkIr1iTcSx24E0lJSpmkVEgmjfN8YfyaSyfbrWbyvBqX3VZLZnwbUXNVqkp3Pift9sGTB@22jKjcemwfL/7Hx6Oo9db/6Nh@fGyPbPgfHx8/hoZL3U@J9@GqN1I1/7UTb1R3WhUR8THAzLhc22k1siKaCynAMhXdUh95LWKEd2OrFQOh9vnzq@rz5/i/uqxeVakhtIKhXQ0BfDBmAEfmABE8r1apAc1wXdJYqQ2NV89boYkZ5OdX4PScAJsd/uUl29/B3/jf6//4GeGb5wL0g@t5jaeXgD9BuJ5fz/1nQ@B538LX4IcOYMcg1/MGGinQNZiavHAuzOfMDZ68UGMRNjCNWoMGXgBCp4@zVPlWElgNkAx5f0Wr1ZpmMkK1Ay7h3Lb2li6OCFW6bSTRwQUtkIYUgULkc9Wqss3Mak6tVnO@pViqVku@WSkUqtWMbwHJphoYAUZ3tW4Ve1Y1PhYwO6y/8RmcP6Oq65Nchbt3j/c/drAzHoOkq5Qzb9@GTu12z3DabXTPvn3LtTncQ1Iv58GeKb19C30@KYAM/MT2Vy/LINEqsrpIYai5muc5/BtjnOZwp6jLCVS5bCZjO63kL3/wne@0knXcQ0BdcwpGgHGSfK1WyDUahRyYCyVBqHIJtimFH6TKijBPyBwrHUisybjvpZSKAnWdJ9GfxGtkpwE9wsWLXM/jtD1ILi/wnZkuXINL4KaUy8yR5Ap8KVX2f/UtgTS2if9rNpvZVG67uH3//Px8haVBqlW91urKvH6tVXA6ZV7t@trL8YSAdu9etgx1VspUW7F2@8Hu2W4bP3yG68QwVhB0pPQvhmuAYyfZpHNf@fJ5E0t03komK9X7rNlLeRJPVn04MQmklJTKtOBxELCNPh4bmtJYV@7t@JgoxSwMQrEx3a9TzJAeLnk6xO73t8ARWox0cHXa1U0zUPd@ZTtm78ro6Vux@Mmj3f2Ds7Rag/FMPdzdT6unz/biClrzCzv1zqL96cHug@NnEODk0cHu6cFnR18cPDsBdzf26o2m65o@0fWr9mRy9Ro1guttfQyui6utdw1Xe/VKG9OLVBnlu7p6/5Pvvf/JP3z/0x@8/@n33v/0R7/8@kffg/sP4f4Be//g35bz@Pzl1//kD97//k/B8T/B/R/h/vkvv/7db7Ob2v8U7j@PuP2pf0fg2E0q8cY2XoAIJbWU2oahZbtcBmSgrrUYpPWbv/z6hz/75de/9WO4/5l///jm/ds/X3//6Lubbwz3wz@4HeYH/w7uP2JxBbA/@H3mhu8b8L/P4H7rx@9/59@z/1/4PzT@9P3v/Ck@fMs//vFf/Pn77/wHVS39xb98/70fvP/uD99/9zvvv/v999/9B@r73/2XSib6@IP3P/rj//onf/Rf/@T/ov8/pM8/usv//Y//8V/9v3/1///Vn/j3z@H@92D6@V/9B0Djv/njn@D/h3/8N//xJ/j/V//8b/74//6b3/wX1PB7zPDf/9m/Zc@//s73/vq7//Svv/P1huf3bn1@fQf3r/8XuNw9n3eJ5y7l@liXr3@t/PzP1MYiFcABqpqdqMA97s10kOtjGZLxH9AJf/SP3v/ubwBu/w5Agu3/BBv8mQW8vk8tX3655Jei0r@Y@vJLEKe@9MWqL6NA3yfkrQycbub@WwD4kvqyi4RQkOj/g1AARnyoAGwpcQqCew2Z8y@//qc/Q/cwJLr@RjS@TOAagU0g8NugiN/HzhwWIwr7fSQH73/y7fc/@wfvf/J773/ymzgWiLlyejctKh@YcgTA/B3gELBwFzgAVFCkAtl3K6aCYauGU2QxJfXyJTTCFphAkNmO5bNgiykNalbQDAFBUt5mM1MpnJOCexrLlcGGc1UpGIRTzCsFXnsp/AZvKjatgx8FxY/3EjQ2Sjj5gEJ3HeLFQCxMul0C4YBM92gsELKeekra2/UpC5hChwaNgWCG0Okpp6hcqlR/AAnWpw8IxoWRp2Iv4f2y3ijVpw2M7h3NAsSR2oMkAQq/DZyaNt6BvU7jBPjY9ME7yEqpnko1SuBSp0WlqaXbNE0lTwtHy54itNzoTgju99u5T8innFLi2KwAVCXxofGZWkDv0MmxHfBvpbb94tB/YKT3NoaHdprS@mFuzH8HnWl4HwDiFUXcJga3KGJu7oP3lEWVosnCK8VigJpL@dOKoQNlUFKxFG3fFLVA@pCHj7lqbHDG6LA4iUQCTLUGl@XaxyCTEeei4nqagytZlF@sEK5Q5tAZt92wvYSJEyq6bT/YhqcC/4Mtun@WlqS6HUskUaRPkiAlMZW1c3acFSIoIbVt0wKkKCD5FHzwvn8fzFBD9L1wi8UX4ZjMQBctgcHPESHG02/NCHTeQEcmiMQeu4M9ewrcfJrj0koBFyMENqsQ@5ZdqdTfKbliDN7UPsGv3PjfW4HGwm/9SrUaVnrjWqQTHGgExrAQazT8VVeixBqnB2cAfnZMFDUjEeD9r3NFNZfP5dVsoZAvqkquUM4V8qUskLJCJq@qSjmXK5fKxTkty32gBunKdidfa/y9G9f/8ffWXetd8Yo1viRTic7SzmMNs842/SVw9ZVrZbgqnWihNZdoZtL4U7NZeEIe00q@eL61ZV6LWOQW3Wl2jevbkM3YtTjFWeFP4CKxT2LkE3CDCxLBBSjibxk4Oq76y8P4pTq2RMwpeUAeIdYC5GHRQSteX19H7lh866uvPNJoAGMvHh3G4oD0w/Db8KLRk4YS/b5cb@Lo1HdAyIOjL45Oj46fSA@OToHZ/hZRsxkpFp/P5/1wFp9adXJ8fBxDagOiU1bB8PMumUwm1LcD9vlUi6mqqGbFrCIqWfx/wKDi/@7wKvxVfEKorBojsXH0qsIdQ0S@B0T6nsKM@cLCmEFjzT9N3IjR5cImINF5DD9H1DyP1eTQ8wwPdz@BxgD0tcgj3DDr2eTMZhsz9/TuBoj9Ifuw9r5jg2z068PsadYF83pgsNOkoddDDdVOuiPDG26AeDYe4REo3flfFsPBqAMZxIUDBrAHD8e07XUARfLsZEMpH4cKInBlnmqIAPCnR589PIu8zw529x/GCmTv@MmDlVfeB8qTRweHZ6G1yHyDoPkwim8dPHq0avVfQBOrVBjeIvliOg1DCzzwnaYXfUuJFwGIIt3yPZiE3ChVHf3ePaWuvBNrXoI8q@@9Sz2ZjErZslLOAwJAqQc6yO220YOyxzVPO3ESLjl5hFI8yuL1hmZez0muCBJ9@wvoc8AsTEgj9hg3CJYVdtDFcGMPQa4e4Sd98PNdXgwPnvbws704S9LB7@dOxmSjI7zQCY2OMRjCIHBlBwCxjqYRuD/2gvBRkRqq61YHj6VB3W74mGvAcVXa6JNMTKIzumq5lC@Vs2opXSqXcnmlkM@nFTWtFEvFMhDkjFJSCqV8WUmXcuVsDkYM8M2Xi7E4EFKjL8swGiocB@8KRGt1UQt9DdX529KwEYuzuSnyBj8MH9dC@4RwOoTh8HtIrke3P28bdU7N4dmErEIgRo10SfzwcD9zeMhxe2jBmev9DMf10JIvZTLFPY7Tqc8@jGoqx9ksDHgBmMcsmczePsdNWASow4Ljhmg5KCCbznEGWvZ3Dw8xnVdoUTE8gF0wH2YxA0sRwCy0ZLOUz@e412F0ALfLEsrRnB6gBdNEn0Pmsw9@HPdZkJ9MBmJ4yuBYDA@Dsu7uctwRs@zuos/ntOB5ltVvoGWXXhzngAWQkOMGYBg4um5xXAeMiIoc1wVTd6aBG2r8R50Glqdx3IxVEFYRx00ptNa94IAf9d0xmYcPH2pDr6cP2DVz2LsLWQMfYzo5OOx89llnMOg4s92Dz56iz@efP9RezSZOZ9Dxg3XacNkQBnwuRrPVC/J41G5r5lqfb4CPteLTnrV1zFtbew158q8BJjJqfw4@n4PPupVMFhtcIwDt4LU3gvee1qE@wUV96Hva6XBVRFRvNtZxog77DP2ud3qkdR27ivZpfSvJJ9OzZiFzXqXOZMQL15nqHH37PP2mHFJE4XrWnNYz5yCjFFX//ATPtaZq3uDSW6MdIG2VLW1HUXOpaQUVltr9JEmKyg6v3Nt@wz8RdtRsrsK1dnZErqmc76hKqVIovtiecJxQwedOtlh5w2eSGULwITSL5zvFfCREsZjSZLVSLArVOdSEB8NSZ@Lp7TbPX@nahSBgXpF5gvyzz5fPaBGNap@fpqd1likyE6rTugIk2pvAcJS5EVcPVThM8MNNLMYBRDfdyVSQMPOcUi5xkL4sC0iLkHrA@@XzYI0kfEUMS0Z2SaQism@@KaWCIOFm/Lbdb9Pv3pCXUUjkmWPP8dAMPTAbbHCj0oVbiZ0hi02/Ek9QeUwHPzNJTz@DhMcUkRA2gaEUy7FYw2cyT9gXN6q@FRU@SIf4PWHbkfA7mN6SD1NHEDiR0xkwByPp6Fh6ZrlaP4zlTJ960kMdd7B1A7d9dqpVOpjih9QN26pei8/FOT2kjedgUf8FDIJavQEmrUd4mjrRhCtarnajUW/XR/po7M1AlKF10QgDw5BK9giDxCM1wamCdn0PipupWqglSkdrYhqfxho91GuxV9@7nlQqADuv6nX6pWQujseQdqz6hJbnRHfwBMzRcaJPdDxq0h2@bB0g4D5U7fVcbDjEqoa5OHJZ/YSHGmiGrjFDvke7nplXB/Umur/FR03kuHNRbL49jzWgS1Vnca3uTjrsu2GZDshAheoU3JRirjoknXrnxbTq1MfAuZOqCZUVkUiIVqXwb00YHdtSuz5dFDtbb6pZFTcwpdVMOa0qMCTCUAnQcBfBnoNbgRv8FZRbeJPnCOHSmWlGUtKKrqQ9@8CCWs5UKljZ0EzUCm9NSKnbJt@ziVYTaaNBD63SLGrpIRkb6SEPoZ7qmsnABZEXX@8UUrmcIFRfQ@6cBN@T9oSdXLXH75G2AA4wsMOtkkKu2q/zL4QqvyXUXf11NdrkvBBrYCenJR5vQeX6wpg7GTUzZKugpK/Ftjg3NddLKEW10pwkmqICxcu8HdS4rxrcOdT9nIAIQaKrJsA0VMEt6NKMzVgwCgu3MbKKpg5NpZTVqg8SG/vkhed4/HAs2yDJJ5NFNZkUklUU@7fA3SdPlJYkgbAl7yk7HDAqXIUrqyDjRcjSjSywZbUCiF/zWM9wxyRXjsWvY/PreS26Le8bZDbTUmJgvUfIIJWIEZmuF0vtONmiJlFq0LmZ3fru4Olu1Yfe3Y/FK3Qn02I3Cmn5h0lFeetjF6lTtcYL9m7hBgtINUY1lzTJub8qr2ahzL2IHcrnXsdYrbJ9B3It1ZBbMY6jPZUtwJXyAsspeRenasPJ/nXwSfTKY5SgCa9VWA9sngvvnhjmdSkrNqjkx5P4uxTUCG7Kasjv4kDQ57Si/R1R19fj62uQbOd4QFrN5mNxyw42S4E86QGlg5Egn@dwJkQn49Pyi@KL0ovHz46fHR@S@5lKqVKKSgWt@@m0klSSNXIfGFDj6QFIHG@JnVfeWZ/T/WDxarwyTmZzyexSsHp8Ws8FC6q80miISk0lO4CrpAL0pq8UxMzbBkO8BvUoqODz/jd@nJvWSmBXgcmrQJ3mU2qjoWyrQnz8/ut/gwePrg@@2H1EkljAv/2zn6nFv/2zf06X9ZLzKit0MQ6QaFQKxfh5nGUhVyQCWNhasRJvyL67UlSEuCsyG2QvH3ff@iogeDVTAr/9Y2bjClBr8XI8Fi89fvmWkBqIfo3eYGCo1CTLS@JUogIiFPzJO5w9eiduvQRa4roJGcKTMgIHMx7bjUZjG@eGSbKRwrNyap7OtDfn1XM2R4ASxLZFf7q7jT/9Reiw7bpgD2xg3a7pJN9QCIgcsvz@N35XVQt/@2e/3RLett@2vwkktVwuFxQ1/qubV9xXp6JCXnSLbd6s4KlTscR2oSN1fuWyLzoHJ/Do13yBt9UdDU8uovZ007AuIACO52DG70QCA1AhdzzuF/NH4Dd4/sQ3dzRXL@QCmzvDL7/TyTo8fudWZHlgeMNJh563O3NmR94xPY0gA74YIKdTc8e0O/JIw/kB@nEgF8QfgEBd0hNLhlEPDxPQjycix4k6FdpUYw0UrdcGsDYWixcqMQIpj/FccGva73P0QLFu9k71seagehPwD05dHvUQDPXW0OPKwUnZJX4oPCZLa1wnyX22ZVyk551tynu4yeCYHK1aQnUx6HiIgcMTu/7hG7obnJPQht/D5YKd4ADRt1HZZQDPvnceBgi/oLsIgWVEdSE@H1CPloikaPlTQSZwOpc50HwsrH6iCweaEM2NQ4y05gyoXiYLtdpAWjw0q4RK/JpK5TzN@MS6QuubHsw2SK1OgPVG9SO0JFihVJ1h33CA9VJKEcUklPGiIaPlSNX9nAAgaxA8iIwKiXBvvd15RZXw@DoSEP@kwM8/m45aj9j34z1i@ao8yVXH8CgADG0UAEPKAzy1wqoovYSqnckAjwNgX5BsZyAbrjvR88VSjmZIw@PFASjwo0ugquzrGJZp5vA0b1iKsjckpn6pm/S8vJ9tVOamsU5J8Qx3raCeOmSwCwJFHajKpZJCLfDlNHN7cHD4aPfs4EGaiEoewfFMVtcOYflI5TLvFPXvmxN36KMRBmHdV@oUcgzJeTedvC8nBT/r96PVnopmOIgAPweEk3ljPlmnwRx9hN9eYhGTsdZDWpWmYaykf@Qcz3qzc02Gi1mZOCbiTVC5Qc@PxzlEaUwrjii49P1vCIMF83kbsAHhuQG0kVZADfjUrQ2CxxgValDM5dadzQbCKooNpjGA2zfxY2xJ1M8UpbZJ2nc0kjxDJdAwpFPStpWkdAF1EgzryU/dZLULvHnAU5BLfiJc@yUwrD7mgmcVd2bvzYL24yf@iREOKkQAnlgIj5D84s@TwGeE8bkm7wnXl5pD3tQBQ2mPkxhRPzDpyTw@yfSBQrA3EvIc/kmtulcNA3Ts3kxCZWZWb39omD3@TTSNMbCaRp9Ppbr1ela4hiSdMRAndwzEUEd5TaiiW3/JLfx@udxqWZA/advSr8iXjx89hCZ/qtOD2M0X59sJOQ2srVDFImh1HoEeHD8@0RxXdwRpjO/DUAji8fMJfiIStPbIbWbOae7THBZNxl4IlHOge37p3b3ZmTZ4oo10Pqkl2REoTMqARjFqmsSEoKqRSglQRK1pnC/VUZ1bblxOuB7UKdTQ0fvVDlT0RXXu1i/5gVD14DWMJpGHJOqqSmP3IFDdhcdKrRv4MeWHZ48f1ZM1jWCs9TW9IpnqhMgBiEIRhp7t3nUcbbaEOkBVKFZ57BQjRRi4UkmusVyWmqw1ksCybszPI5uqXZAkKblA4B4/SfsY59RvNmnVWWDBbKzX0YENbZ8dnHFpCOtMdAEdLRzeZpRosQP69SANhm5IKegQODtFmHo9d@8edWN6Oep1NZMRADWrc4jNBczlQ7HHqc4drd7jw4rUxsYaZQCqpMqa5V6hDmRgeTP54o7twBBR7wEPec8FElJHPb@Xhje75wK21QPFAvfYCcn6Vm67dGzsffPL8mnhAd/tfK5wae6Va1sgojnjaAYc7UpibBHQWKfLsItmArUddjV5rF3Ycq6X6ZYyJaXY04t5vZTJlrp5PVvuAJfY7edKnV65qBXz3Y4Mg5tHg0gjAz/XwzH0x2T7d0t2E2NWAhm/31eAW@/ly/2ymslmc51SvpfJ5folRctmCz211Cl3bufaFvlBcSuguzh2rFLgTzczd7EbtN0PLfwP';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le._Vd 2=>+u >
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Osh was added by inserting one more case in the `case` statement:

```bash
a=$(printf \\x00)
b=$(echo -n $a | wc -c)
case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;; 1*)echo 242;; 4*)echo 78;; 8*)echo 166;; 0*)echo 50;; *)echo 58;; esac
```

[Test the code in all shells.](https://tio.run/##ZY7dCoJAEEbvfYoP8yIDcRX/SOpFsovd1VAMV1IopXe33VUR8mrmzBzmG0a7cpo47XFFK56DUfBSwGlghgRgcnsGYKa6/TcCYJwFZYx7IQHqTah3QiyFfMvI9xleFGHYjGFv@IEPsYW4ou1dyS6rGlW1PU30Yh3bV9X0D2TZhxDbYHKyHrEovnhzONw2DnposZt3NzjtirlF1QCerXdhkKYSTjPJfIXBgnGiKFlIvq@QLBgSRStos@go/wE)

Note that value of `$b[1]` is the same in bash and ksh, but they still get separated by the `case` somehow.

Answer (score 5):

## 245. [RETURN](https://esolangs.org/wiki/RETURN), 11454 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEUCIMD3Uy2ppdM6093StNSnzxxSzQZJkEQLBNgAKJGtVtfMJDXXE7tynclc13h84zMziRM7SVV8UzfXk4pdrvJ8TbnyyT@gnS8pV8rzDyZrrQ2ApESq1ROnKiAB7Mfa77XXXms/FjqaO/zVr6J4sSPbnA1M22Oe7nqs5xjnuiOxnRm7rxluXs1GIgi17QwmI93y3EokyhTGLP2CHVhdowduzLPPdMt4ozvgpzI2duyBo42YN9Q8sBgQij3Qzbejtx7r2qORZvVcgMwydqSBZ3/SPWNax/UcresZtgVeOcaeWaY26vQ0BhC6M3Z0j6LPM4iie0Zhln0KjD22HVfH5Lu669roWGSspo/G3qwBlhJAaI5hP9p@8tm1wGXGPtMgZ2NTn17Li5Jhzw3d6V0LoSjsi5P9/euuKvuGaFts/2b@lCx75riaqV2PP8e2J5594F13z7PtgW5pTJXKknrds8B2HO1GkCJzdK3XN0xdMqwuE9lQN8e6w9CF9W0HmszTzVKmlGlvz0NKXQxbmntei7YeXExzBi542uc6GHVoibGh91jfsUdMs9wLSEkpZ@bwGG15GR26kEFANPbKhdA9nbmWMR7rHveE4uoOeUPKzDSsswjHviPH7k26hjUAOB3qdTzxqExupAvBGmzs47CEBhalWuBgkIVje6QvtoULyAu5dsd61@gbXV45@tTTLRfK60rMgLa7MEyT9XQTAsxj76aZa7OJu@DUMbWh1JUiWLmYChudmcxg3fGYcS8oBmRpP1Ni@sh@ZbA34G8OXTYdj5hrjMDb69r9vq6zN/p4CMEjPTvC4OqOrxUrtMV0gLF0KNru0beg0jysS6sP@eqxzgIcZIIyTMXVLBvqzmGWNuKo0B3PqOgQTRiib9sSuvds3bXiHruwnTPW0bsalhkTc/VBX5uYkKLRx7YAJDBcNrLhDS1oMcgWBPawIjBuTCyysiCYTNC2@hh6JbatjbgCDR008YWjAXI4rt@InjEC1DC8uMt0zTWQXEEQV7d6hBbjkJDZUNrFFmfnBvQ6qIqJQ3G7ukN4T/EyLAVEqYWImrhwDA/QAUuxzY50zWEnjq4nOZLqblcbI4ouJgmJ2ZiChwWRCCtrtfje4X4csJOHkLQxYKOTPfnm5xGNSXUWa1fhrgtCNbL35AG7jLXQzAkmYPDYSWhJVn/HXLnV0uGeKh154FxFINYI1IrJZHvsyZo4hgyKHmRQ1tCIJvFclcbmQsKsdq0NFvoMh@pBawAFYF@kqWTdieMgaZ9XqnYGhTZtawD1CYV1JhZv8kIGmgDwr@emmX6uIw7wNrIvqIZPhoAh8AfQBbLCRxuqUBhvoB/6NRqk69rmhOAgpOthZ4RagaAY40GffcH6mmFiEPDHqHiuHd0F5MQwE6uHLT8yLL0nsSAbRHIc6IjnkJwGkZID9IbRAmGhTAEwNIRNRUWv97/9e73BAOLZ7nZtp@ej6xeA7F0aFzXKLIxsDBHWtjSTsgVwaUydB4cEzjXT6BGJ06yZnwRlglK9sCdmj1FHvTCgyw01oLQ6UIeup3Mktyce5DHNRtoZJ4cGx1wo@EjrQMNSApQ2FVtk93ehlbrQzQlnxNHE65eYON5jcVd@kdiqJLY2WjpkLiklN2OyPKgCwkmb5AS2@G2Y88X20jjhepprG73IeOYNbUtlYpcJ3bo91q1EfCmOeDrudOJJCcl0Ilk16l2pb1i9RLwGuNiAhOPJarfebRqV0@q14ItJQjQXGA12Vz3RTQpIaqhTnMsj4CwkoGRfiL5pwc9221jl6C0tOGPFXHc75w5R4lsQL21EEKBDkmvq@jiRkZQkkgmEW1lu9FhV0mtx@AWuGKepeDSeWiw6xQAlXSoodtYTw0ayZY6HyGxApVjuGGiug7jb1QB7XBzRPODn0qxDeE3DIFAWookXehyodgcIaYBH1CV5l8PwIhJKP4Z5F1ruyXpvoSMDEYC@7Lk3qLFpI2tAecKRB0iHhYlqA2gaCMwLss0LwlMil@UinVlAUDC2js5KYseAToDdDWi6j/MLZQPwrMphIDbeSRZoz0ib4ajG@YJ5h8ExTWMjIA/OjHV1pDlAfHQ@oGAiE@p/LjC9zO6zjKjm88t97EYX8xx5W/wKiPQb@daehIVf7ExIaFgfeGxTswYTbQD0wrYgiNbt6mPPJ1RQEtcDUnR9vCFH0R88JXcYid2/njYNIgFvNE8DiTxvPX8o1JC6@Dy7CAwZ8n1cEGA9wwGyBCP5tdQB4Pxa4sJLBFnKwEthTRYCDgCQTJ/q3YkHVA0Q@GJodIeAs5g7i9NFPghdTx6cFlMHyi72w6QxM0rjnhqR5NAJs7E2ChFb9GY8MLhiVI0lB2r8RYfbY9bc0YqI7TCLMBAsuEqyJgHufSDOkW3ZKyKFigyjRZBlH94OwIkdI0cMA1fAdlFnDdnksImgzYBqQM8H/Bt63titwDhheMNJRwJMkU@c2YF3aCGyyJ4zMzybmzum3QGy7EL/lIMU5O6kY0yvFYjcwjZ85UbOgQHru6wOI/frCWBdIt53gWCS@y4CL3gJRLgpCv4UAJCAJKioRN8lUrwPROV4ZnUTwhJSCmkmYN8VkmDAgGHVfI7M23I2X4HT9Vwi2GJmJBmhZNfpkkFc4EkxegSnbEU@WSraHfMY@UQQ4NHXTFeHtzUxTbROLE7lEpxXSLLLyCefAGlLUHLGaGwaXcNrc192757PU7ANEPCQbeojz5SEMJ/4krQEBAVg/OGHQ0uefUzMbiIJBfnkailh3XFsh6frDR37gpEDgkUWK3XXHiF1Z8@J4UIOGmRaw0LZ3h9LaSjVVrIQ4ZhK/HI8Lr2yDStxGd/Y2IhX4g0YMTc2tsBUQ9MWmlJg2iKTSCaEk9BEIdJkQt8mhUC30/hVM4h5mjzF7jDF0f6NMU5ozUole5rWmor/VvGdhHqGEQOgRXxBPPFkvY7GZFJoXEBBpU5/ufS7OOoddx1j7FfC59q5xu1@LWSpGqDhbAcFgyoyL7fXyajuAHcBwkB3mHDirWamddq6bPVSrat4GkMnq1q9A4WC9BIjaeDYE2BDks1cRVROk8lmFpiPTj2eiW8mEiURxDiQRJKflpIpjdd2Iq7DaJhoteJQqX79NLtDh@KbptVkMqwqyAcyPMBrJ@LSZQnS7yRPk6k4hE3G0yC61eNxqJkuVoJLhca@tFRBh0@/wStmN5WKUPcGqRTvG8MpuKHQuxz8aPLmDdIuHkcnxDBzonEub@wDyAdWACuh5zWhNfDq9BnS0aU0PrP7XCraxcfeo/2IPqXW@uxwf@9pnZIZau4Z8BTiAGFl4JWhVpyeBNTAnPT0yCoYIBtg6s5zghMHmPig22WizQhM7PJMLAwXXbYmNqA1xHjaTDRHy0Vwh5Df3aUyUCTkTiFv41@6QZY4@Mo8hUnuA8XePX60ND82OgN@gnVdE5lv0eEFAKu8yR179ApljAo7IBnNAgYTcAv4y144F2DZloi0MBDn7MWE@IQIQJAbclvISRhLMBhx35iCSBzF@RSf9UeOFbn/XdsC4VSXnhM1FBgQcpyq0qWV/P8RZ6SkrjvvncDpg3Fsal2g98vRtQTWggiBAsnyap9k9UbE14UDkuM/VEZgpbqahfXXM0hOnRjuEKsXZAkcBZw@1CoKqTi5Q7V2wLrA5Q6gpvWp4XGpFXr4MQZ5qLmJJMpJ21zOQCxDHhkzFUzbEQNrd0HC14FXRl8@XcL2rHPDsS2sZGkPogZSVMU2uBb5quoFNNrePlAfrK/fVZFDjd1wVhbqdjHW65XbdaF3WbZpD2y2CQCImpLEEfvAwulNkHI8bQw9ynhDFbQ9sEHUX8ZBXQ8nTAvZUN7UEFImeOkVjAJsdaHnAGvKfHzw1R6wIUo@k4H8B7YMXWEhF2K5XkZ07LI5gL8EYCLeYEt@pY@HM2cJnVzbnzfxaPKQOiafydKAhYRc@T38DQVd7OTcBfp54NULTKvKvkcyAU7eLcrVS6Vf4lZ4t4ESRq85o2tQFUuR3mjwefsi4WrJS3QrnCoQ@yPb0@QvJCDR@IgghywaTHDl@EZcFkV8CuTF1AaTe/q5jFRqHvN0T@@ujHuq610ZfXFwY4FhZfUEnmuqpgWXRQ8oJn8HdRCGvF7@QSqFhJ1yF6bNMw2D/Mlwokf07tBmQgtEjMWSCTBADEFWFqHmgQFEuSQM5i8HRTx7AmJdTzeNkeEd0IS9aaHsIhHxlpBq@b67QG/mERwZOjDkfMJhPsjgpPp8jLIGHP4pUHKKFUR8iVepo/fkzXlsj23bAbnSZQrNKahh1Y98D9l2xz3Jm0IEPNQeje9uMM4/OXyw1z7aPnlYlyeuI5tGB2hET2@PQJg1oTusuTBvOEO4B7hjWPbIgBIFUb45M5/atseZB1w1uNsVxYBBHI8etB8d7DzdfvotP3M0ohujialhHiuxawBhHMcEc2s0XbtjA29hTdbGBMzF4c7hoyCWz589OthuP9g7OjxZiObVxDQ0ZSqPzwbrCvQ5gjBFyvCqPzR7y8s5JKYuzSL4xAZlrioD2ZSJIjxFdOOJolQmoQeyyDg8iiLOAms4z@0wVcmUy72OVirphV43lyv2tX6vl1OVUr5fyqv5DDyKhbLO3hK4KOpTmrkBE58VwQkkTAMyTy9FygUcDoiiXeBYZivzFfrekrluPq8Xc2Wt3C2Xy5pa7GU1tVTU9UKxn8tk9IKS6XdKSil7a@YWsoGs1dw2ohkg6HU4WUCeQPwS8FrqDjzzwOtdsJ6qqoVuvl/Oqr18JtfrlDP5Uq@jFLVOWc/0c1lFVXpdVakEYXFGFajEEBoMuUoLWNPAS1TAMxkJBtPFJqYlxmAN2ic4sSySmHGwhoyCg@@RQ4@Jv4KMU7O@ex7dg/VjnKLx3QvoPsLV4zknS9bQ0QcsESAuIktOJ3Aso2O4fLy0sAqk0qefq/zXB/JjvlQyVxj5BS5AL5TvUlHI/dzr95ecVXI@E3EoM@fOWXLmy8/LC79@YW94rQQO48tRfHzZemV8N7xWAofx5Xl8uNy9OrprPqtAw8gKFBkuj6@M65rHCsAwpiLFtLikPvcrkd@69XQ/rZXeawOFcZcpbr5U3n7FVyva/ko5YjPvICfAiT2ygX9@ZOC8fX@px0RCCbwVEYJphOWJpLmPOl8mYeL56vUdYTEiTgwM68wmwTk0tTOSksdYwihGZ@bNkH0QNeixBHojUzd9@Pg16vTpsQIAB93rM3PkQdOe/tAPQ60mP6UXToCuysHyVO5S8h29PwEpSO4YFpo/ACaWSwTZ73SMdaBQE7jzIHivAKuwpxOQRFUpJymB2ItLJ0Cz@TzsycEhAXY0EuKW5//ZUuV7E8eDUP77P3@7B41ws4mG2oxkwdDQtvQLwo/@2hbzg6KFHqtbdz7qU8WQ6UNRdjVcctXM0LA6amp9URxqzghFLr@5AUHxAZhwC67xnPO5mOC9OpEKo0peXmdgljFi3RXQBHttSYQnRkK2aWs9qgYuChs6BXKwsXkz6FMuFC4wPDDyrEtoxcoFm28V8IYTb8KfuDvgQ81ojPG@rYv6kJm81lF0YJG1jqHf0uiOdjbp2SJwelRkzFhhBey89DRZJ/ZN7Ywb22hcXXxeQMcYDICf8N/rwC6GINuQUCpf0OtDeOFaE3csdqCxPOg4ZKOuMLolBcfkz3Ughr95LjSsrzXDpMcdGj1ELkIXYOmoonE/k7hQaca1aja1zgxF9eHHYxkmSAwO0Jx6N5XKZHHYC9d@F7cirQ@PYyWFL5dXh@Y7qXiVrBKvZL6DSuQTyFRmf0/VBxoWBi5jpJmi2lswrqXowdTx3LQClOZtxK6puYBant8c@jk0Hz1uQ3ccmbogdjlz0y3IPs9OsAVg3WqyT7b8Xt21TcPFrm2uo6DXF@DmaeJeNnosTEkbqyq2RzyTOxRD02q6YHc9XMpdg2h3oHJ8FRXXqRcwR7LXVVrXvsB7LWsxtM91/lw90L1Zmas7UCzRJJQwuitHlF73Q5iK24Hosboez1bmy@uaK92X@0AwxbEooN0Rr13DtF12TM/bqmXgQDD@XI3RizVoaJZI60GL5tXB/EyNmeTPsq5pV80c2GahNJA1eKxt/InTxzHBf9@V@oXUS1E@TL0C/si2FP@9luyfyc7Zh9qOliYcXLRfMN4yAq8iYf6i5PoCgiSBO3FWF24/U6KQkszl5XUN4HSHF9oseP8aI8u62g1GlvGM@G1g/zBAuQQGz@E8@K@TWu721Hp3I083oi1@qBALjXtm6jCQ0fNGkzI1o3xkCCWTuTux6psTfaKvpFWHnVc6bm6/RQq5e6YyfjFi/mwnzgjhXGcI9caXH@@UaxzD0XYrgdFMAzr5BzmdlfRuDDz6GEXuIzAcoeFmwIE1GS817pIUZz29veaG46Bn272lTKLPx1Kk0of5qSVG3tXpvlW44sIgrm3Vs5lMxudvFuavlyy3CV3ZMOwrgz@XEiaXecpzWJwNcRaMq9OYT6VC0xtnroiTmnejTuq6GQECLpdly7B0b4bPdU2yitp2bNv8mCYEotszkH8DrhQXfj7UlDd4I383GJvPfbg4c9Lpr5v14AOSL51C7aHgfRs2LE693qmZRVyyhl46uGa9fR5oYSL3Q6nAME@TS3zrhLme8fRnVBSpJBVv7ZGcnbU7uqnx17SQuy2@spS9Nb6QZfH5ZFrbwvUwvgI2X1GNXqNb4xlUltEDIWeoj3Sy3iIdaL1XEzd4rQWa2niv8JZovXFduLEBhMLC59Jq2wIr5dkWiGWe5gx0lGtMXBX3XdcR52BWfWXlHoy0gc4PVd1GPedTHbh1mEuDc@PqSY8K33XWhWB868ftqACd6UyfucF7ZYSPZ11oz8now1N11/p9lzYqfaijS/LKxYQP8IrW0B5aQ33IdwKFtnXdAzDS48fhbisE5N/fZcSIRi3uVFqsXdM2zbvULtJITjFtu78yX3t4UKsHQT8q3pnWAQ//9cFpQBjvqZJo4F/Xd4b6BIYt1/bssS6SbR2oiRNG/LmOkgYLPL/uTNStswRQI8H7143/g/LpQLO98Zhe7bE5celBQUU6X7eqKfcpmbtgheHxrUccd/WB3ekOjQ9lqaNrnmWcycGsELfeKt2OF2rBYOIDdJZMAyrPmUmIDfVF/2N8HaxrUn@CiQ9doWF1G1fY7sRxZlgTnm0z17Qv5jRieQ9FOJXLVyDQsC4H/urgCm/iCHB3XbCL7JZlEH8xcS2CESOOTLeoZ4BpUdbOKi1t8VzoHdksf6zjja6VnzK1sIb7MdOi/tYHmiA0FmZvwX0Jf5YWpFcOWNZwMnBvkjs@ad8DNgsfK1t6e4CHmq81NG9UGIU0y3@tq2/VlHELN7zb0HIT/dYVlvytSywEp5iiZhvwasML2nCydurMNMYufzKxr65kGm4uI9@Emq0Wnf326el9vh6Cpg9xeyPbwYNEwFaIXUd3uzidjhSZ81Cc@lj2ACizaLI5cAC7sgg3V65XN//iqCd@@UQfaLjN8pGBOy7NFZgBMV9fxL5LxN@caK7xzYnt6SvjvL6YfZcoH2sDo/twqRWCCIPa9ffk8ddSF0Cnmw1xMTRcOs8RGG6Zg0KE4yiMONcG/n@V9HZt@j48JX37NMsC4@TvBWfiAQv2jIcGXEBAf21lWqtm5u0xyZEzMt02KW94NFPrv1di2OpNAbclfzEZjSeu/1qdOu3bWZyyHp2Ru3thAIkUXwNlZkPN9FZPay/M1AL/5Q@Yc@M6rvwrw7QH7KtShgG7BgM4MulrkG4Hhu8jzYPeYa1AZEr/jounOBEiOrxwrwEv9CwTDcvwbp/08TwN5KbgjQXigw@eTJQf4VO6/7ExiCera@XRrRwNjPWzrokH5T9WOuBkGDDxmA6yozE8S7@I@34y@q4fYTDaWPrFogx360JQBYdY25p4Iu78v22MKdw6xlTYtFRYQA@W@Obe42fJAEsGwy7fEvshvlQH4XDimrO5ae1mhBXIZ1jAwK2nzTdDBFLGA53UHTylTZx3CLc9xtNVNBQ8sFdJQ0czGJk@SqSCwWUyeqB3cXXyTnl4Yj8G9g6GuzEQ49FTHbcWXKMx6wNj0Ed2VzOhznp3Su6Yol8xlsyFcW2sd6DtzblpNd@2LvIHmqet4bVospEkxtD0QVwyzI7uvKJZxAXzOkH4ZqYe6lMSXdYjFO@potftciYdp/OW@tH1NSF3bNsWfxKxzsBLeXw7QYJhhB53X6mXcN/z0ii5UrC7WeLDc75VRe/xQ3/riuzoHdvkTyzGGrJhGXxjguYYuis/MqzJlNyYCDzfavGIbwHOSEWcInGH0BkvDJDNw53BuNGNbzN2r0lgwEqfay5tF1gtCy3tQr77jqSh5nRtXHfzDR@56rZwnOwD9D7cZs23NXQAlaZA@LTuJNBJ8IGsmqPOiB7rZZnl1n6qd/DIXofOn3radBXjuXz0zHe8dvgrIHlICAoscQQSU/LDg951cW@51o0xPYj4X6xElSC5J4befaMlP0Brw95Ec9GyRtLwyg61vIkO2CJTF70h7tGUPW8d8XhinE16d1grCxZgJiMd17yXV37WIpbtDgkr7NWr/CEBdnR/6zfuMgQSEJiRCovba9EWo4f/4c7nMgzi7UIONQBMpuIAyNqH9xVA5ieO5b9WFsI/nUGKZEKVA27aPzcEbobjn012pUArUpTOWBHaB7v9WRTVIkxQsvdsR2IEl0hoqVQyGeGBcOfFwAKwAIrUuqDKB64xxmXACnkEa/RZs8lil9NKpqJcsToTKgI7PeWx4kUKCPamY9LJ8pQHb8a003osLorxWLxlVVgmHoLrJogBK8G1Jdi@QS@e33kVcH1NNilbCktc5SotoLuhupihZvVMnT2zaDkM@DaHK2bgWj9OcJvnL/6w52vRIW1RIwPEdKgQ1IJlj/ShfbHF0/VTBy5GQy08GAdIdCbXCSHubjMQJ7zukCvPsS/Ys/2Tkq@Sw1e5BZYjPkET5oI3Lq4U4fFCjzcez014VMxPOAwVFAp41MnIAmLf84auxI4NOjk4ceZnAXxFZJbn4FRwL80OWE/HHXV0IJRWP0zbPqNDIpiTX/whV0RCx0L943pB8qSAaCFFPP2pkPaPbteeQK6DSN7oju2DJLCSQYab4Foj6b8i9yQeliQNKYCRYqAfhJLhSkJ2t4@ZuMfiqFkLz/NXjX4itv30sy@amdP6OzaS9f/8bTl56Vec8KlYLrhCmgUg1StErEXvPHjPfeNMiE0FnmB4ZtbwOc8L3h6oFYwjGR6bDXDMtsd@ryEdT6TSKMRGX1VAAs3UzoGikBGphyKE1S9IUQgdzrKQzJB6Mhc6GFiTFDXvdfVYYsKXv8Rjj@UhQVS2ooGJK5SiU6So9AKDxKbsLRsikgHPouQzYOMVaaKelVF9J9hvnV3cBy8/0DsT2gt6rkpqvk7FibXrtQaZgBbaqO@o@aI1VTNia1rcOwUuzK/UVmv6aUb9EmrddiDUPRl73t6TB5cxqZF5@9bVZkwQruJVvm8fyETs8ujgaO/4ZPvk2TG0wlVAfvb56Z2A1iAW0YG8oW2SJimoF2SFPoL@hDbU65BgMY3VUFFhMhlZPDpFoH5dC6IQ48YF0rQU@gPBV4V39QX/mwA@TesbLMCoAxgCsQ0B2bDWsPCTMerDYn5YX6cPYZmBNB47UFgxeDpiBS2lqhJYHSpLhMq6Y1Wx9YXd4m53qbEPxnJ7tW2tBMEaC9Nrhv68iCur4OrvpNxjGCj/58vNY7m93ARzS7kBNHQNwuxvHzx69nRvORjgGL2J6tbLef/MICfO2NM4KxUoMaKj@n5AXDqsC0ygANzqD2ZclaLuXehQLJ84dkc8MGEo5V@IzBETaqaOqjxPq7wuEgnKAfIgVSzWtSONfWO6kMVgjF6I7pIXMSQC@0IYdZBxSfBjjpJKSgmvoBgYq19dQdc7IiLu0@u4u8j@pIMeh0XDMXri8j63ZqgKRx2XwX9hVApM6imbMn84U06ZyFS4Td0aQIED2GSVj1EsxitCiPG8C2F@UZsg5Kn3SqPZetqq7x8FhFHa1MaousyHfmJ7eoW9ntikbiAgJiF/QYosNa75k5qWq7QkNQYg4gBnHoxbFN/B/nEduTPOmhF9X8S5iYUDFQBxPZz@gWDPQWW1/KQmV4jHq9z2da8FQyVJrq6vaynkElx2brgGyFzUCH3kcUyglFgav@CoyJUUTbBt0wWepAfDN3AoHg61wJxIdH6MHyITLSZEASelkGVMMyGCsG79pi4uGEovQKrsvuSBYwRHMbsLccZrG6IINTcAUds/i1ZBNa4ksFWY50xwe1gjfiNIkIUKmcShNzIXAFdoJWzp8vvf/j2uibDlgfn7vnma2QHbb/q2Pph/K/BRFLD9k9Cmgu0H3PZCxia7qX7NT94XWdYetgO8vC/cKBPShEB1LZUlbG1s6S8OjpjbRaWo2JYjkKDnzYQUBnEOJCnAvxEgxTm1MYLzFOZNOI8n0fwCUATwCvAD2RvkaCg93TlNoBKuiixjxnHOXqItevqUL5mTTq7XE9RFCUyYXMgXcooMmRTPgwhJTcgATwzxCJPJCtDEyLkxrr/sdFmtVmOC29VMvV6octyQY9qLrPAyzGgMYCNcUGgyCANB5iHAr@EHS8S0lJLEoDiQxZU40rSezVENuMEEGQAkic5WoFgA2E3bryrAY0ufesQxzQIBCAi2ZS8ooQ0iEiEiHjdqTLzeHeengHDyaKGDSovNIDxHsGMEqwirkLX5grW8lnXqa85kgHg/WYG6Fpj/0Qp1mhyzUHHKTT2OietaGLE07P6xZeMc3D7kliVUWc3KSiG5gKGCHxXkF7v6W4gSOjcQi65uvLLH7vbu3sHnh0fHN/T5EGT8OlicxRu1VEuU0s3T0BAP871cqTv78vHjnf2gKhdzNZ8FQ4j5lsjr2VyV2vWcrkn9OT9wdTNt8riRkJK5a8S010jcp63FN2Of@8oLgLv8vMeNVBPJy6vmaa3RsqI3kn@7SkdrVNpE5AJTyyUNrfHr2cQshsrYT1AZuysFp4kVPEqMZ8w8@2x@MNl3WPDg4EEsQAEikhxArcDYIAOHfH5mrkFD5drgXSJ9fA6HNGeGOVqAPAn0xmPXmit88zWdDTV3aBqdCIzdPdT@x/WUBIo4Qg0nkjs2DS@RjNDsRx05ICBiCV97/LQylWiRL0F6WimuNLtNeVoQXzICnQDiix9N3CE7ssdsPvX0QA9MT4ERYQ8mfNVHZ59PRgDXp9dTHUmsDqyJCIGhouJhVrlADT3L1502TaF@OkiviRrU/IJLo14@MU1KQ33aMwZAwBPJNPT0TxXgqMLT3Vho0qdmxYHG8Rr@DM/ZLFbpR6nQm84j15qaZFg9fZpAnTCVU2BN0T1@8fw8nhRu4ADp8dsNNH9dU@gXdETN83vEXBnetc5WDlXGX9O4WC6jXh08qA7NAikee84jMML4lOiPtDFLTEjTpMskRtZEK2GlXc9JMrHBlVVYLJUigRpe5AEMM4L2yUSIwxKomDkh16F10NW1evh6Y4xZU5GkUzBTIkkWw8m0XRjKcRoqGQEBCYJUKNo6ti2rYI449koc8yAM@kdI9RVDdYsrvElBIi6MQj@FuqBSs8a9BZVB8x7Ia7VcrvitsUxqygzQ4iaVl2SIdgUJCRhUqF//3DHUGioQR03zOG0MZOH@N3TL0qGCAGdGGozB2gSQzEmmg89FpOcKpymFKM/iQ/8gM2R0WRH1XvzSxPXGmFyleZnqFYypL1s4qPb9YXUm/31ZkquXiZhZn8nA6CQbidiwrqSym6lUzNpMxCwc6u/dw@mcqxhwEm0JpKMpAIkxM1kFfAbOox6zqjGtloj16uomhQAryGeXEOCdK0uXMe1Kjt2DkToNLg7vvImYS7oMM5KkXEH@sIfE5DTgzCWqfqNvRWDyMSOVwjxIsTZm4J3cOk4RzW4dyzRzVPUZUXkw8rvbNaoatsSNL2XwCvSd/YYGwq4iYff3j7cD4Lka6uwqvzW8B0/4G3hEh9GOQN1d5PyFZZ@7Exaf3sVJzRTXHMmVSUIFThNQiWhNa8kkEJNf/SqqFJiQiG0VsuepeD5ThYdSLbI8@zTWUnNRFr0Pkrq8KTjCZetB6ZzpfbXwWhSbWl96fXp0dnT0ZbKViEd3D18ISg5Ai6xM912vIlPXXOzjrmh0U45E5U3lXlGWX758CewuXM2G1FiEkk6TTTF@2kwUwdIoFjfThdJm@n68TVlJJlQ1ecwMQ2YtY@z2enDbQ/piSyLKL7a1hWmBAf7MdxtN@9xtnhkO4rsGYQOvD8FVtHyUtYqatpnKqfetqqRm1F/8fOMqfXnUrv3iOyNZ38DXIb6@f/UYzcdK/tONjU93dnK5NFQeNx99dfSt7e3t3IN0/qiZ38qJmY3aX/zZxoaq1lR549R1ldN48@xLQc3kBOkXP4sfHX2z7brYfnhlmQJGfJbgVlg@z87YG7jO@gz/ZH7TWzBraO703@AACcxynYhNPJ7Pxo9fxLG4b6KKokRn9GtTNWwwpbFV/C8/PHwd9aINVX7uwNuLvo4WSlFuBAPYsoHtPNqI1hCscBWdyfV6HYzF//LvIHzjc4gHfWY1eDTyQVyFWbQh1inI22ijAAZFVSHd//btb0eijSkiQuNgn6kNdZPjilK6p9xjU36xVlQp5Q7vg3NwBV7hxWRFUVtBey40NzZt6DyEwkO7MnvBLWz3ADOizMcGMnwMHH7cp7Bx/@UDVmvAUItXpXI/RDWZFUuCbUN3roLtUej@VBLhktqBvYpW0S9CtFRPt3nyIa5GFwzXChw@mV/20P6RcHt4/eX/95c/@ssf0u9HdP@nSDRYfReb543TRnAxoYH0ifm2xxZ7zC/Lgj/cgRVd0AFMFpuXJRptNPBBf99GJnpfc/N9GqGFIOZBboHzaQalG4m@gzZB7GPnjaWLNWQWmqkIPNdkeLxQsnnZEAW24NqAH/3hCq343CAX35lAbl4brHHbdSv1jUSb0ebpaYU6090vtjru6HkkKgJpSKWeAs/oI/NdrmdwS1Lbt4VIHY1E/06vRoRFL@E6TYlXV03pRapa9f/ASlVDG17cBHk6vRLF2otGKtWkvDUbfiZr4mlDYm2eX3q8qEG8qVqzVrd36ZbaWEdiPGfHC/b90xeNZm05Dj@a@/dT2JnvQzyN2CkDJh5q9qp21bhq1q6uajX41@h55b/B9ap240@v@VVdAxReV6fY6K2m3GjJLb9BT8EuyQ10keQWGBrwbgNgsxmJXiK@sOYpqb@qi02lkD8VGfWJzQr6dV3GKsqmmpXz008Le2okqgqCvIleb3FkAv6iHIkil17mzHqZHF6@//pf4916//W/AStkDb8xRr4PLfx1XuPv0Rv8vfbwd9LF39PX@Dt5g7@nHv6OXPw97uAvEq0zBixSbCtjZs4zyplyBgaDZYBDHWaGSg@HhIzOMrPMjGVGttIDkw6/DJiMTJ9lBixjZSxFAU8weCzjoakPrwH8@hCLAz8jk8HIM@cMUjFxoCHdsfR@22bJVqTJhJc68DaSEpcycakQjxun@cL4tZCOt1vN@Gk1Krutlsy5PqbmqqQ0@OqKtdt7Tx602zL2g9Zj@3D@PzwcLVpv/Y8O7ceH9siG/@Hh4WNo9dT9lHgfrnojVfNfW9FGdatVERGZJR@to3Jtq9XIimgupABFVXRLfeQ1jxHejY1WBETi588vqs@f4//ivHpRJUNoBUO7GgL4YNwAjtwBInherZIBzXCdU6xkQ@PF81Zo4gb5@QU4PWfApId/ecn2d/A3/vf6P37GEs3TJPSDy6tagq4k/pLJy6vLK//ZSCYSviVRgx86gB2DXF410EhAl2BqJpKnyasr7gbPRLLGI2xgGrUGBZ4DAsWIhmlSuvyR@Lt9Y9r8asWBSwLpNeGvurVa00wmWe2ASzj/rr2lBZxklba2xDq46AYSm5IkiHyuWlU2uVnNqdVqzrcUS9VqyTfHEonyzauR2VIKhYqayyWT1WrGhwXhrBoYIQrd1bpV7N7V6DiJueWdPpHBKUD6UkBcqAj37iX8b0tsjccgrCvlzNu3oVO73TOcdhvds2/fCm0Bt8HUy3mwZ0pv3wLhiSdBjH9i@wuwZRDKFVmdpzDUXM3znMQbY5wWcGOuKyRJl28mYzut@C9/8J3vtOJ13AZBrjkFI8A4Wb5WK@QajUIOzIUSlFOI8X01iUGqrCSvYrLASwdCdzzqeymlYpJcr@Loz6I1ttWAbunixS6votRcLJdPJjozPXkJLoGbUi5zR5YrJEqpsv@rbyRZY5P5v2azmU3lNoub909PT6/x@Eg6q5daXbmqX2oVnBG6qnZ9ZfF4IEO7dy9bhjorZaqtSLv9YPtku43fmcOlbhjtGDoSEY7gMubYiTdp@i5fPm1iiU5b8Xilep@aVynlWTRe9eHEONBzVipTwaOuGzH6eEprSrFeuzejY6YUszCMRsa05aiYYT1ctXWY3e9vgCO0GOvgArurm2agXf/CdszehdHTNyLRo0fbu3snabUGI7K6v72bVo@f7UQVtObndvLOov3p3vaDw2cQ4OjR3vbx3mcHX@w9OwJ3N/Lqjabrmj7R9Yv2ZHLxGhWw6219DK7zq613DVd79Uob08WqnPxeXLz/yffe/@Qfvv/pD97/9Hvvf/qjX379o@/B/Ydw/4C/f/Bvy3l8/vLrf/IH73//p@D4n@D@j3D//Jdf/@63@U32P4X7zxfc/tS/F@D4zSrRxiZegAgltZTahPFts1wGZCDXWgTS@s1ffv3Dn/3y69/6Mdz/zL9/fPP@7Z@vvn/03fU3hvvhH9wO84N/B/cf8bgC2B/8PnfD9w343@dwv/Xj97/z7/n/L/wfGn/6/nf@FB@@5R//@C/@/P13/oOqlv7iX77/3g/ef/eH77/7nfff/f777/4D9f3v/ksls/j4g/c/@uP/@id/9F//5P@i/x/S84/u8n//43/8V//vX/3/f/Un/v1zuP89mH7@V/8B0Phv/vgn@P/hH//Nf/wJ/v/VP/@bP/6//@Y3/wUZfo8b/vs/@7f8@dff@d5ff/ef/vV3vl7z/N6tz6/v4P71/wKXu@fzLvHcpVwf6/L1r5Wf/5namKcCOECa8JkKLOzOTGdVFsmwjP@ATvijf/T@d38DcPt3ABJs/yfY4M8t4PV9snz55ZJfiuY1xNSXX4JA@KUvGH65CPR9xt7KwG5n7r8FgC/Jl18shIJE/x@EAjDmQwVgS4kTCG6X5M6//Pqf/gzdw5Do@huL8WUC1wXYGAK/DYr4fezMYTEWYb@P5OD9T779/mf/4P1Pfu/9T34TxwIxV05vp0XlA7OmAJi/AxwCFu4CB4AKCoUgvW9EVDBs1HCWL6KkXr6ERtgAE0hTm5F8FmwRpUFmBc0QEGT9TYpkmsKJEbinkVwZbGAApykZwCsFXjsp/ORxKjKtgx@B4reSGRobJZyhw2mDOsSLgXiYdLsEEgqb7lAsELKeesram/UpD5hChwbFwDBD6PRUUFQhVao/gATr0wcM48LIU5GX8H5Zb5Tq0wZG946yAHGkdiBJgMJPMaemjXdgr1OcAB@ZPngHWSnVU6lGCVzqVFRKLd2mNJU8FY7KnmJUbnRnDLcsbt1n7FNBKQl8XgOqkvnQ@EzNobdo2m8L/FupTb849A@MdG9ieGinKdUPd@P@W@hM4X0AiFcUcacb3KKIubkP3lMeVYqShVeKxwA1l@LToix0IAYlFUlR@6bIAulDHj7mqvHBGaPD4sRiMTDVGkJWaB@CYMics4rraQ4uxhG/WGFCoSygM@4c4tshY0ckP24@2ISnAv@9DdoCTCWpbkZicZyUiLMgJTGVtXN2lBciKCHZNqkAKQJkn4IP3vfvgxlqiN5zt0h0Ho6LFLTuypRCjiUjCfq0T5JmPnRkgljksTvYsafAzacFIa0UcD0lyedFIt@yK5X6OyVXjMCb7BP8qJD/eRtoLPy0slSrYaU3LkWaokEjMIaFSKPhLxwzJdI43jsB8JNDpqgZiQHvf5krqrl8Lq9mC4V8UVVyhXKukC9lgZQVMnlVVcq5XLlULl5RWe4DNUhXNjv5WuPv3bj@j7@36lrtilek8SWbSjT/fBVpmHW@bzGGC8hCKyNUaaqIai7WzKTxp2az8IQ8ppV88XRjw7wUscgt2ix3iUv0kM3IpTjF@e5P4GKRTyLsE3CDCxLBNTTm73o4OKz6K9z4YUC@yi0oeUCeZKQFyMOjg1a8vLxcuCPRja@@8lijAYy9eLAfiQLSD1mwpCsaPWko0ef8ehNHJ98BYw8Ovjg4Pjh8Ij04OAZm@1tMzWakSPTq6qofLkSQVWeHh4cRpDYgOmUVDH/VZZPJhHw7YL@aapHx4lWFO6KqopoVs4qoZPH/AYOK/7vDq/BX8QmhsmqERRCR7wGRvqdwY74wN2bQWPMPbzcitOLZBCQ6jeDXn5qnkZocep7gWfon0BiAvhZ7hHt@PZud2Hxv6Y7eXQOxO@TfMd91bJCNfn2YHc06414PDH54N/R6qKGWT3dkeMM1EM/GIzxnpjv/y2LYG3Ugg7j2wQF24OGYtr0KoMieHa0p5eNQHwduLiCFHAD@9OCzhycL75O97d2HkQLbOXzy4Nor7wPl2aO9/ZPQWuS@QdB8GMW39h49um71X0ATqyQMb7B8MZ2GoQUe@E7TRW8p9iIAUaT1PIfmaSBqN1nutAojfKm6peBURz4m1xVrcvQI5XTTPnKAfLZQ6n4n1ozeF/WGFusDCa7vNErvUrliKQsVY14@mYwae0P8yqlTdfQJezbQQcSPPMadjmWFn9gx3MhDkK5H@B0l/GaaF8Ezvj38VjLOlXTwo8WTMVvrCC90QqNjDIYwFFzYAUCko2kM7o@9IPyiYA2VdquDx9Mgtxs@5gpwXF43@iwTkWhyWS2X8qVyVi2lS@VSLq8U8vm0oqaVYqlYBrKcUUpKoZQvK@lSrpzNwbgBvvlyMRIFcmr0ZRnGREUQ4F2BaK0uqv6v4TcUbGnYiET5DBV7k9CS0LqhfcIEHcII@BEq16N93JtGXVBzeMgiqzCIUWNdFt3f383s7wvCDlpwEn03Iwg9tORLmUxxRxB08tmFsU0VBJuHAS8A87glk9nZFYQJjwAVhwjCEC17BWTWBcFAy@72/j6m8wotKoYHsDPuwy1mYCkCmIWWbJa4fUF4HUYHcNs8oRzldA8tmCb67HOfXfAThM@C/GQyEMNTDsdjeBiUdXtbEA64ZXsbfT6ngud5Vr@Blm26BMEBCyChIAzAMHB03RKEDhgRFQWhC6buTAM3/MwCKpKwPE0QZryCsIoEYUrQWvdMAK7Ud8dkHj58qA29nj7g18zh7y5kDXyM6WRvv/PZZ53BoOPMtvc@e4o@n3/@UHs1mzidQccP1mnDZUMY8Dkbza5fkMeDdlszV/p8A3ysaz7tWVvHvLW115An/xpgIqP25@DzOfhMV1w8NrhGANrBa2cE7x2tQz7BRT70nnY6QhUR1ZuNdZyuwz5DH1NPj7SuY1fRPq1vxBPx9KxZyJxWyZmNEsnLTPUKffsJ@pAf0sXk5aw5rWdOQVIpqv5BkITQmqp5Q0hvjLaA1FU2tC1FzaWmFdQSa/fjLC4qWwnl3uabxJPklprNVYTW1pYoNJXTLVUpVQrFF5sTQUhW8LmVLVbeJDLxDGP4SDaLp1vF/EKIYjGlyWqlWExWr6AmPBicOhNPb7cTiQtdO0smMa/IQkH@@TfjZ1REo9pPTNPTOs8UmyWr07pS5ceTWeZGXD3UmzHBr2XxGAcQ3XQrU0GinRCUckmA9GU5kUwiNUL6Ae@Xz4MFm/C1YFgy8ktiFZF/ak8pFZISnito2/02fW6IvVyERN458hzP/9DZ32CvHkkZbiVygqw2DgAaQ509Hfy6Jx01B0mP639hfCJDKZYjkYbPbB7xD51UfSvq2ZD28TPOtiPh50e9JR@u@yFwYsczYBJG0sGh9MxytX4Yy4k@9aSHOm7G6wZuu/yArrQ3xe/XG7ZVvRSfi1d0Ih6P9KLaEaPHtHoDTFqPJSh1piUvqFztRqPero/00dibgUhDddEIA8MwyXYYh8TTQcEBiXZ9B4qbqVqonEtHa2wanUYaPVQnslPfuZxUKgB7VdXr9IFqIYonqras@oTKc6Q7eJjn4BCGZh1PzXSHL1t7CLgLVXt5JTYcZlXDXBy4vH7C8xmUoUvMkO/RrmeuqoN6E93f4qMmCsKpKDbfnoJQBL2qOotqdXfS4d9ry3RAGCpUp@CmFHPVIevUOy@mVac@BhaeVU2orQXRhGlVgn9rwgDZltr16bzc2XpTzaq4GSutZsppVYFREUZLgIa7CPYc3Arc4K@gAJMwEwJjQjozzUhKWtGVtGfvWVDNmUoFaxvaiazw1pIpddNM9Gym1URqNeikVcqilh6ysZEeJiDUU10zOXhSTIivtwopWlJ6DblzYometJPcylV7iR3WToIDjO1wq6yQq/briRfJamIjWXf119XFNk8kIw3s51Ti8QbUri@VuZNRM8M2Ckr6UmyLV6bmejGlqFaak1hTVKB4mbeDmvBVQziFyr9iIDmwxeUT4Buq4Bb0ac5pzHmFudsYeUZTh6ZSymrVB4mMfQqTEBL4wV6@2TMRjxfVeDwZr6L8vwHuPoUichIH2ha/p2wJwKsIFaGsgrC3QJluZIGvrxVADruK9Ax3zHLlSPQycnV5VVvcv/INNptpKTGw3mNskIpFmEyr11I7yjbIJEoNmqTZrm8Pnm5Xfejt3Ui0Qpu15jtrWMs/GCvKGx@7ZJ6qNV7wdwv3ikCqEdIT02Sn/h4BNQtl7i3YoXzuZYTXKt9CIddSDbkVEQTqqnwlrpRP8pyyd1FS1852L4NP0VceoyjNElqFd8HmafLdE8O8LGXFBomACRZ9l4IawX1nDfldFGj6FVW0v7vr8nJ8eQki7hUe9laz@UjUsoONXyBYekDqYDDI5wWcEtHZ@Lj8ovii9OLxs8Nnh/vsfqZSqpQWxYPW/XRaiSvxGrsPPKjxdA9Ej7fMzivvrM9py1u0Gq2M49lcPLsUrB6d1nPBympCaTREpaayLcBVVgGC01cKYuZtgyNegzwKKvi8/40f56a1EthV4PMqUKf5lNpoKJtqMjp@//W/wUNUl3tfbD9icSzg3/7Zz9Ti3/7ZP6f1vfhVlRe6GAVINCqFYvQ0yrOQK7IkWPiashJtyL67UlSSUVfkNshePuq@9dVZJNRMCfx2D7lNKECtRcvRSLT0@OVbxmogAzZ6g4GhkkmWl@SqWAUkJfizdziN9E7ceAm0xHVjMm42LCNwMPWx2Wg0NmkPYryRwnN/ap6m3JtX1VM@NYFCxKZFP93dxJ/@InTYdF2wBzawbtZ0lm8oDKQOWX7/G7@rqoW//bPfbiXftt@2vwkktVwuFxQ1@qubV9RXXqNCXnSLb0St4AlascR31CN1fuXyL2kHpwnpK8rA3uqOhqcwUWu9aVhnEAAHdDDj9zmBA6iwOx5djPhD8Bs8S@ObO5qrF3KBzZ25uAscZ@3wKKFbkeWB4Q0nHTo7eOLMDrxDOlkhA74YILCTuWPaHXmk4UQBfZTJBQkIIFCH98SSYdjDgxH00UpkOlE/RJv0A0HRem0Aa2OxEslKhEHKYzzj3Jr2@wIdjtbN3rE@1hxU1QL@wQnSgx6CoZYgOnodnPpdYojCI79U4zqL7/Lt7yKd3baJ@XDjwZE/qlpGeiV0PJAh4Olj/yAR7WwXJLThd4iFYFc7QPRtVDIawPPvzIcBwi8Xz0NgGVH1ic8I1BdLxFJU/lSQCZzX5Q6Uj7nVT3TuQAlRbhxmpDVnQFqwLNQhBGkloFklVJ7YVCqnac4o1hWqbzpkbrBanQH3japUqCRYoaRGsm84wHsppQUlK8R5UcjFcqTqfk4AkDcIHqpG9U94TsDuvCKVR76@B8Q/KfDzz9mjjik04ryK5atQZRcdwyMAGNoIAEPKAzyBw6sovYSqnckAjzZgX5BsZyAbrjvR88VSjjKk4VHpABQY0iVQVfZ1O8uUOTyZHJai7A2ZqZ/rJp3997ONSvQ03ikJz3D7CuoHRA67kCTUgapcKinUQqKc5m4P9vYfbZ/sPUgzUckjOJ4v69ohbGKhcrl3ivz75sQd@miEQXj3lTqFHEfyhJuO35fjST/r9xerPbWY4SAC/AwTzuqNE/E6BXP0EX7zikfMxloPaVWawlhx//g8nlvnZ7QMF7MycUzEm6Byg54fjQqI0phWFFFw6bvrEAYL5vM2YAPCcwNoLa2AGvCpWxskjzEqByHMFVadMwfCKooNrv1A2DXxI3hx1DW1SG3j1Hc0Fj9B5dswpBNp24gTXUD9CsN6/FM3Xu0Cbx7wFOw8MUle@iUwrD7mIsEr7sTemQXtl5j4p18EqJAk8MTJ8DjML/48DnxGGJ9rJrzk5bnmsDd1wFDqcRIn6nsmnTJMxLkeVgj2RkKewz91VveqYYCO3ZtJqDrO6u0ODbOXeLOYxhhYTaOfSKW69Xo2eQlJOmMgTu4YiKGOAluyim79Jbfwu/Fyq2VB/qRNS79gXz5@9BCa/KlOh8qbL043Y3IaWNtkFYug1RMI9ODw8ZHmuLqTlMb43g@loAR@tsJPRILWHrnNzCnlPi1g0WTshUA5B7rnl97dmZ1ogyfaSE/EtTg/zoVJGdAoRk2TuBBUNVKpJBRRaxqnS3VUF5YbV0heDuoENXT0frUDFX1WvXLr54lBsurBa7iYRB6SqKsqxe5BoLoLj2u1buBHrB@ePH5Uj9c0hrHWV/SKeKoTIgcgCiEMnVPfdhxttoQ6QFUIqzx@IpMQBq5UXGgsl6Uma404sKxr8/PIJhUSkiTF5wjcS0zSPsY59ZtNWnXmWDAb63V04EPbZ3snQhrCOhM9iY4WDm8zIlpc2UA9SIOjG1IKGgJnxwhTr@fu3SM3rmOkXlczmSSgZvUKYnMBcxOh2ONUrxyt3kuEFamNjRWKDVRJlTXLvUDd08DyZvLFLduBIaLeAx7yngskpI76lc8Nb3bPBWyrB0oS7vHTnvWN3Gbp0Nj55pfl48KDRLfzuSKkhVeubYGI5owXM@BoFxJni4DGOl2OXZQJ1C3Z1eSxdmbLuV6mW8qUlGJPL@b1UiZb6ub1bLkDXGK3nyt1euWiVsx3OzIMbh4FkUYGfiZJ4OiPyfbvluw6xqwEMn6/rwC33suX@2U1k83mOqV8L5PL9UuKls0WemqpU@7czrXN84PiVkB3cey4ToE/Xc/cRW7Qdj908n8A';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1nuPLconsloPrs  \puts~-<idV=>a$f 16=B>8~+4783ngtl{Num>Ehar Cr;reu Ugele.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

This language is different from [RETURN by molarmanful](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN).

RETURN code is next to Flaks on line 23:

```
(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(()()()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()) (()()()()()()()()()()())
```

Brainfuck equivalent (`.` means print as number here):

```
>-----------.
```

Previous polyglot consists mostly of *Add 1*/*Subtract 1* RETURN commands, hence the need to *Move pointer right*.
C/C++ code had *Put character* command, it was fixed by adding another `()` on line 187.
Also, RETURN has *Exit* command, but it is 52 bytes long, so I don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

## 250. [Retina 1](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 11580 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWmp771zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@yFbemjTk9nAGG4Y9fwKfoCgyi6pxRm0afI2FPH9QxMvmt4noOOJcY2jNHYv2iApQwQums6T7aefXotcIWxT3XI2dgyptfyombZF6bh9q6FUFX2@fHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao69cD3d0q/Hn2dbE9/Z96@7F9jWwLB1pskVWbvuWWTbrn4jSIm5ht7rm5Yhm3aXSWxoWGPDZejC@o4LTeYbVjlbzra3ZiHlLoYtzzyvRVsPL6a7Aw88nTMDjAa0xNg0eqzvOiOm2945pKRWsjN4jLayiA5dyCAgGnvtQeiewTzbHI8Nn3tCcQ2XvCFlZpn2aYxj36Hr9CZd0x4AnAH1Op74VCYv1oVgDTYOcFhGA4tTLXAwyMKRMzLm28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAWaxdzPMc9jEm3PqWPpQ7soxrFxMhY1OLWay7njMuBcUA7K0ly0zY@S8Ntlb8LeGHpuOR8wzR@Dtd51@3zDYW2M8hOBs1Iv1nBiDqzu@VrLIljAAxjagdDuH34Z687E67T5krcc6c3CQD8ozlVi3Hag@l9n6iGNDd3xBpYdoohB9x5HRvecYnp302bnjnrKO0dWx2JiYZwz6@sSCFM0@NgfggemxkQNvaESbQbYgsI91gXFjYrGlBcFkwuY1xtAxsXkdRBdo67CVz10d8MP1gnb0zRFgh@knPWbonokUC4J4ht0jzBhHtMyB0s43OjszoeNBVUxcitszXEJ9ipdhKSBKPcLV1Llr@oARWIotdmjoLjt2DUPkeGp4XX2MWDqfJCTmYAo@FkQmxNzYSO4e7CUBQXkIWR8DQrq54299FtOZXGeJdg3uuiDUYrvPHrHLRAvNnGYCEo/dlC6y@nvmKa2WAfdU7SgD9yoGscagViymOGNf0aUxZFDyIYOKjkY0SWeaPLbmEmYb19pgrttwqB60BhAB9nmGStaduC5S91ml6qdQaMuxB1CfUFh3YvMmL2ahCQD/el6GGWcG4gBvI@ecavh4CBgCfwCdoyx8wKEKhSEHumJQo2G6nmNNCA5Cej72R6gVCIox7vfZ56yvmxYGAX@MiufaNTxATgwzsXvY8iPTNnoyC7NBVMeFvngGyekQKTlAbxjN0RbKFABDQzhUVPT68Lt/0BsMIJ6tbtdxewG6fg7I3qWhUafMwuDGEGEdW7coWwCXwdR5cEjgTLfMHlE53b4IkqBMUKrnzsTqMeqo5yZ0uaEOxNYAAtH1DY7kzsSHPGbYSD/lFNHkmAsFH@kdaFhKgNKmYkvs4Q60Uhe6OeGMNJr4/TKTxrss6SkvU5vV1OZay4DMibK4nlCUQQ0QTl4nJ7Alb8Ocz7cWhgrP1z3H7MXGF/7QsTUmdZnQrTtjw04lF@JIZpJuJynKSKlTYs2sd@W@afdSyQ3AxQYknBRr3Xq3aVZPateCzycJ0ZxjNNhdjVRXFJDUUKc4U0bAXMhAyT6XAtOcn@O1scrRW55zxoq57nbGHeLEuiBeOoggQIdkzzKMcSorqyKSCYRbWm70WFbSa3EEBa6aJ@lkPJmeLzrFACVdKCh21mPTQbJljYfIb0Cl2N4YaK6LuNvVAXs8HNR8YOkyrEN4TSMhUBaiiedGEqh2BwhpiEfUJXmXw/ASEsoghlkXWuzJRm@uIwMRgL7sezeoseUgd0B5wpEHSIeNieoDaBoIzAuyxQvCUyKXxSKd2kBQMLaOwcpSx4ROgN0NaHqA83NlA/CcxmEgNt5J5mjPSL/AUY2zBrMOg2OazkZAHtwL1jWQ5gDxMfiAgolMqP95wPcyp8@yklYoLPaxG13Md5Ut6Ssg0m@VW3sSFn6@MyGhYX1gsy3dHkz0AdALx4YgerdrjP2AUEFJPB9I0fXxhhylYPCUvWEs8fB62jSIhOzRLA0k8rz1gqFQR@oSsO0S8GTI@nFZgPVMF8gSjOTXUgeAs2uJC68QZCEDr4QVWQg5AEAyY2p0Jz5QNUDg86HZHQLOYu5sThf5IHQ9eXCaTx0ou9SPksbMqI0HWkxWIifMxsooJGzRm/HA4IpRNRYcqPHnHW6PWfdGSyJ2oizCQDDnKiu6DLh3R5wjx3aWRAoVGUWLIIs@vB2AEztCphgGrpDtos4accpRE0GbAdWAng/4N/T9sVeFccL0h5OODJiiHLsX@/6Bjcii@O6F6Tvc3LGcDpBlD/qnEqagdCcdc3qtQOQWteFrL3YGDFjfY3UYud9MAOtSyb4HBJPcdxB4zksgwk1R8KcAgAQkQ0Wl@h6R4j0gKkcXdjclLCClkGEC9l1BBAMGjKrmM2TeFrP5Gpyu5xLB5jMjKwileG6XDNIcT4rRIzhlK/aNhaLdM4@xbwgCPPq65RnwtieWhdaJzalcivMKIruMfeMbQNpSlJw5Gltm1/Tb3Jc9eBDwFGwNZDxkm/rIM4kQ5huBMC0DQQGYYPjh0LLvHBGzmxKhIN@4WkjYcF3H5en6Q9c5Z@SAYLH5St1xRkjd2RfEcCEHDWKtaaN4H4ylNJTqS1mIaEwlfjmZlF87pp26TK6trSWryQaMmGtrm2DaQNMmmtJg2iSTRCaEk9FEITJkQt8mhUC3k@RVM4x5Kp5gd5jiaP/WHKf0ZrWaO8noTTV4a/gWoZ5hxABoCV8QT1Ks19EoikLjHAoqd/qLpd/BUe@o65rjoBI@0890bg9qIUfVAA3nuCgY1JB5ub1ORnUXuAsQBrrDlJtsNbOtk9Zlq5duXSUzGFqs6fUOFArSS43kgetMgA0Rm/mqpJ6IYjMHzEennswm11OpsgRiHEgi4idlMa3z2k4lDRgNU61WEio1qJ9md@hSfNOMJopRVUE@kOEBXjuVlC/LkH5HPBHTSQgrJjMgutWTSaiZLlaCR4XGvrRQQQfPv8krZiedjlH3BqkU7xvDKbih0LsY/HDy9i3SLh5HJ8Iwa6JzLm8cACj7dggro@c1oTX06vQZ0tGFND51@lwq2sHH7pO9mDGl1vr0YG/3eZ2SGereKfAU0gBhFeCVoVbcngzUwJr0jNgyGCAbYOrOcoJzB5j4oNtlksMITOryTMwNF122IjagNcR4OkyyRotF8IaQ352FMlAk5E4hb@NfumGWOPjSPEVJ7gHF3jl6sjBFNjoFfoJ1PQuZb8nlBQCrss4de/SKZIwq2ycZzQYGE3AL@MteNBdgO7aEtDAU55z5hPiECECQG3JbyEmYCzAYcd@cgkgcx/mUgPVHjhW5/x3HBuHUkL8gaigwIOQ4W2XIS/n/Q85IyV1v1juB0wfj2NK7QO8Xo2sJrAURAgVSlOU@Yu1GxNeFA5Lj7yojsFJd3cb665kkp05Mb4jVC7IEjgJuH2oVhVSc3KFa22dd4HIHUNPG1PS51Ao9/AiDPNa9lIhy0haXMxDLkEfGTIUzd8TAOl2Q8A3gldGXT5ewXfvMdB0bK1nehaiBFNWwDa5Fvqx6AY22tva1R6vrd1nkUGM3nNW5up2P9Xrldj3oXbZjOQOHrQMAoqYsc8Tet3GGE6QcXx9DjzLfUgVtDRwQ9Rdx0DCiOdNiLpI3dYRUCF5@DaMAW17oGcCKMh/tf7ULbIhayGYh/6EtS1dUyLlYrpcRHbtsBhCsAliIN9iSXxnj4YW7gE6eE8yb@DR5SB2Tz2TpwEJCroIe/paCzndy7gL9PPTqhaZlZd8lmQAn7@bl6oXSL3ArvNtACePXnNE1rIqFSG80@Kx9kXC1lAW6FU0VSP2R4@vK5zKQaHzEkEOWTCZ4SnItqUgSPgXyYlqDKT3jTEEqNYt5umt0l8Y9NYyugr44uLHQsLR6Qs8VVdOCy6YHFJO/wzqIQl4v/yCdRsJOuYvS5pmGQf54ODFiRnfoMKEFIsZ8yQQYIIYgK0tQ88AAolwSBQtWhGK@MwGxrmdY5sj092nO3rJRdpGJeMtItQLfHaA3swgOTQMYcj7hMBtkcF59NkbZAw7/HCg5xQoivsyr1DV6yvostqeO44Jc6TGV5hS0qOpHgYfieOOe7E8hAh5ql8Z3Lxznnx082m0fbh0/risTz1UsswM0ome0RyDMWtAdVlyYN5wh3AXcMW1nZEKJwijfnlrPHcfnzAMuHNzvimPAMI4nj9pP9refbz3/dpA5GtHN0cTSMY/VxDWAKI4jgrk1mq7TcYC3sCcrYwLm4mD74EkYy2cvnuxvtR/tHh4cz0XzemKZujpVxqeDVQX6DEGYKmd51R9YvcUVHRJTF2YRAmKDMleNgWzKJAmeErrxRFEqk9EDWWQcHiUJZ4F1nOd2maZmK5VeRy@XjWKvm8@X@nq/18trarnQLxe0QhYepWLFYO8IXJKMKc3cgInPiuAEEqYBmaeXKudDDgdE0S5wLBdL8xX53pK5bqFglPIVvdKtVCq6VurldK1cMoxiqZ/PZo2imu13ymo5d2vm5rKBrNXMNqIZIOh1OFlAnkD8UvBa6A4888DrnbOepmnFbqFfyWm9Qjbf61SyhXKvo5b0TsXI9vM5VVN7XU2thmFxRhWoxBAaDLlKG1jT0EtSwVOMhYPpfBPTKmO4DB0QnEQOScw4XEZGwSHwyKPHJFhExqnZwL2A7uESMk7RBO5FdB/hAvKMkyVr5BgAlgkQ15FltxM6VtAxWkFeWFsFUhnQz2X@qwMFMV@q2SuM/BzXoOfKd6mq5H7m9/sLzho5n0o4lFkz5xw58xXoxbXfoLA3vJYCR/HlKT6@cr00vhteS4Gj@Ao8PlzxXh7dNZ9loFFkRYoMV8iXxnXNYwlgFFOJYppfVZ/5lclv1ZJ6kNZS75WBorgrFDdfLW@/5qsV7WCxHLGZd5Bj4MSeOMA/PzFx3r6/0GNikQTeignhNMLiRNLMR5stkzDpbPn6jjAfEScGpn3qkOAcmdpZWS1gLFEUo1PrZsg@iBr0WAC9kambPnz8GnX69FgCgIPu9Zk58qBpz2Doh6FWV57TCydAl@VgcSp3IfmO0Z@AFKR0TBvNd4BJlTJB9jsdcxUo1ARuPgjfS8Cq7PkEJFFNzstqKPbi0gnQbD4Pe7x/QIAdnYS4xfl/tlD5/sT1IVTw/s/f6UEj3GyioX5BsmBkaNvGOeFHf2WLBUHRQo/lrTsb9aliyHRXlF0dl1x1KzIsj5paX5KGujtCkStobkBQfAAm3IJrPOd8LiZ8L0@kyqiSF9cZmG2OWHcJNMFeWxLhiZGQbTl6j6qBi8KmQYFcbGzeDMaUC4VzDA@MPKsSWrJywWZbBfzhxJ/wJ@4OuKsZzTHet3XRADJb0DuqASyy3jGNWxrd1U8nPUcCTo@KjBkrLoGdlZ4m66S@pZ9yYxuNy4vPC@iagwHwE8F7Fdj5EGQbEkqVc3rdhReePfHGUgcay4eOQzbqCqNbUnAt/lwFYgb75yLD6lozLXrco9Ej5CJ0AZaOKhq3NElzlWZeq2ZL71ygqD78eCzDBInBAZpT76bT2RwOe9Ha7/xWpNXhcayk8JXK8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyR7olab0540qKHk4dz0xLQGneRupaugeo5QfNYZxB89HjNnTHkakLYpc7M92C7LPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVdxzI97NrWKgp6fQFuliZuZ6PH3JS0uaxie8QzeUMpMi2nC07Xx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoOc2RnVaV1nXO8V7IWQ@fM4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs7t0ROl178JU3A5Ej@X1eLo0X37XWuq@2AfCKY55Ae2eeO2ZluOxI3reVi0DF4Lx53KMnq9BU7clWg@aNy8PFmRqzORglnVFu@rWwLGK5YGiw2Nl40/cPo4Jwfu@1C@iXqp6N/UK@SPHVoP3SrJ/qrind7UdLU24uGg/Z7xlBF5GwoJFydUFBEkCd@IsL9xetkwhZYXLy6sawO0Oz/WL8P0bjCyrajccWcYXxG8D@4cBKmUw@C7nwX@T1PK3p9a7H3m6EW3prkLMNe6pZcBARs8bTcq0rPqRIdRs9v7Eqm9NjImxlFYddF4buL/9Fink/pnKBsVIBLOdOCOEc50R1NtAfrxXrnEMR9utBEa3TOjkd3I6S@ndGHj0MYrch2A4RMPNgAN7Ml5o3AUpzn5@e80Nx2HPdnoLmUSfj6VI5bv5qQVG3jPovlW44sIgrm3Vc9lsNuBv5uavFyy3CV25KOxrkz8XEiaXWcozWJwNceeMy9OYTaVC05unnoSTmvejTtqqGQECrlQU27QN/wKfq5pkGbXtOI71MU0IRLdnIv8GXCku/NzVlDd4o2A3GJvNfXg4c9Lpr5r14ANSIJ1C7aHgfRs2zE@93quZJVyyhl46uGa9fR5obiL3rlRgmKfJJb51wlrNeAYzKqpclku39kjOzjodw9L5a1rM3xZfRc7dGl/EsgR8Mq1t4XoYXwGbrajGr9Gt8QVUltkDIWdojAyy3iId6L3XEy98rQSaOngv8ZZpvXFVuLEJhMLG58Jq2xwr5Ts2iGW@7g4MlGssXBUPXFcR53BWfWnl7o/0gcHPVd1GPWdTHbh1mEuDM@PySY8q33XWhWB868ftqACd6dS48ML30gifXnShPSeju6fqrvX7Lm1Uuqujy8rSxYQ7eEV76AztoTHkO4Ei26ruARjp8xNxtxUC8j8YdhnRp/ldSvM1azmWdZ@aRfrIqaXj9JfmaRfPafUg6EfFe6F3wCN43TkFCGM9VRAN@qv6zdCYwJDlOb4zNiSyrQK1cLKIP1dR0XBx5zedhbp1hgBqJHz/pvHfKZsOdMcfj@nVHlsTjx4UVKLjdcuaco@SuQ9WmD7fdsTx1hg4ne7QvCtLHUP3bfNUCWeEuPVWyXY8Vwsmkx6hs2yZUHnuhYzYUJ/3P8LX/qomDSaX@LAVGZa3cZXtTFz3AmvCdxzmWc75jD4s7p@IpnH56gMaVuUgWBlc4k3cAO6sC3eQ3bIEEiwkrkQwYsKR4ZaMLDAs6soZpYXtnXO9I5fjj1V80bXyU6bm1m8/Zko02PZAk4Pm3MwtuC/gz8Ji9NLByh5OBt5Ncscn7HvAYuFjaUtvDfBM87WG5o0KI5BuB69V9a1ZCm7fhncbWm5i3Lq6Urh1eYXgVEvSHRNebXhBG05WTptZ5tjjTyb1taUMw80l5JtQF8vF5qB9ekafr4Wg6S5Ob@S4eIgIWAqp6xpeF6fSkSJz/olTH9sZAGWWLDYDDmGXFuHmqvXS5o9GPOnLZ8ZAx@2VT0zcaWktwQqI9fri9V2Rfmuie@a3Jo5vLI3v@gL2XdE91Qdm9/FCzYeRhTUa7MHjrwW0R6eblX8@ND06vxEabplzQiTjaIt41gZ@f5m0dm26PjoYffu0yhyjFOz9ZtI@C/eIRwZcMEB/fWlay2binTHJjRdkum0S3vRpZjZ4L8Wq5ZsAbkv@fDIaT7zgtTx12qczP0U9OiV379wEsii9AWrMhrrlL5/GnpuZBZ4rGCRnxlVc@Fem5QzYV@UsAxYNBm1kypcg3DYM14e6Dz3CXoLAlPY9F0px0kNyecHeAE4YOSaZtunfPsHj@zrISOEbC8MHGzyFqDzBp/zwY2OQjpfXyJNbORgY2y@6Fh6K/1hJgJNdwMIjOrSOxujc/DzeB8kYO0GE4ehiG@fz8tqtiz5VHFIde@JLuMv/tjGleOuYUmXTcnEONVjqW7tPX4jzGELbX@/iQw0QBCeedTEzrdx4cA3xTBuYtdW0eBE6lCYeGaTS4Dlt1LwjzNYYT08RyX/kLJN4Di9g9Lm3yAQDyGT0yOjiyuOdaT9zngLrBkPZGIju6LmBWwau0ZLlATHYE6erW1A/vTuTOaJol4wVM@FaHxsdaF9rZlrOiy2L@JHu6yt4J5o4JAkwMt2JK6bVMdzXNCM4Z14l1C5m6LExJTFkNcLwXij53S5nuHFabqGPXF/b8caOY/MnEeEsvNSntxMbGB7ocf8Vdxn3Ly@MfkuFtMXSHpzx7SZGjx/cW1Vc1@g4Fn9iEVaQA9vkmwt01zQ85YlpT6bkxiTg3ZaLOXwbb1Yu4TSHN4TOdm6CjB3t7sXNanyrsHdNkgKW@Ez3aMl/uUyzsJP4/ruKhrrbdXDtLDB85MrZ3JGwO@h4tFWab03oQKNMgaDp3UmoV@COrFqjzogeK2WSuZZ@bnTwyF2Hzo/6@nQZE7l4dCxwvHZ4KyRp2PGLLHUIUo9490B2XWRbrHFzTA8i6OdL0SRM7plpdN/q4h20NOpFNJes6CTRLu1Ii5vggM2xDMkf4h5LxfdXEYxn5umkd4@1rnABZTIycM16ceVmJVI53pAwwlm@Sh8RXNcItm7jLkHo@qEZqa60tRJlMXr4H2x/psDA3C7m8QT/ZCoNgJzdvS8AMj9x7eB1H7Q7dDy/b04PxqjGyXFX0RcsVgGCwIt3BzStryoEtKc9sfh8x2BuR9eoR/IdcIN9B0wWkXDfkAz7TCIVR9NwudLVQz0yK9vw@uZQ9dbdocGhEtJ/E2lK8DLBcSdwM93gSLUnh8qcgrNh1NXDUwrgqHe7E5yVgOqSGQGmUno6LYqxINRj55yNUFMMBvLoiOOpOa6xbGjEQg2BmhM8HvJOsYTONupMy2WZKNa4vgTg7qA8E6PG@mYY9ZbnmQMbshDmgFTdoBoMrkXHY8Ay@mG8zSZLXE6r2ap6xepMqArs5ITnGC9KZHc6Jj01z3nwZkI/qSeSkpRMJFt2lWWTEbhhgai0FFxfgIXM4ivIcFS/XIeVQwqootqscTUfQMJQhc5Qt3uWwV7YtEQI5Xe5sgquCeUYt77@8o97gWYh0qA1Mj3dggpB5WDOyBg655s83bC6xmMdNRNhHCD1WlxPhrSzxUDk8rtDrlAImuvF3nE5UFMSaCIDyyGfuIpywTEHV8/wyKXPEYPnJjo@FyQchQoLBbz8ZGTD4Nnzh57Mjkw6TTlxZ@cjAv1stu/iFHkvw/ZZz8BdhnRIllaELMc5pYMzmJNf/jFXzkJHZYMjjGHypJRpLkU8EauSRpRu15lArsNI3hquE4CksJJBzp3g@ivpBCN3EQ@QktYYwHYp1JlCyXDFKTtbR0zaZUnUNoY6DmpmP5XYev7p583sSf09GynGf/6OIl4GFSd8IlWKnpBhIUjtChFr3rsA3jPfJBMSU4EnGJ0jNgNu/Zy3B2pK40iGR4lDHHOccdhtkP0jNU8RNgbqE1JopnYOlaeMSGUWIaxxTspT6MCajfSIVLZ50MHAKlLUvNfVE6kJXxKUjnxWgARRAY0OJq5ki07WoiIQDJKYsndsiEgG/J9ayIKNV6SFumdG9e1wD3pu/myA8sjoTGh/7Jkma4U6FSfRrm80yATji4M6oJovW1MtK7Wmpd0T4GiDSm21pp9ktS@h1h0XQj1QsOftPnt0mZAb2XfvPP2CCcJVssbPMgCZSFwe7h/uHh1vHb84gla4CknbHj/RFNIaxCI6pDh0LNKuBfWCrOVH0J/INiODqL9RFGPzx8kINKhrQRIS3DhHmhZC3xF8WXjPmPO/CRDQtL7JYtHIAFigE7JhrWHhJ2PUEcaCsIGeI8IyE8cP7EBRxeCJkSW0lKpKYHWoLAkq655VxVYXdpO73afG7ozl9mrbXAqCNRal14z8eRGXVsHVP0i5x7rn/beXm8dye7kJ5pZyA2jkGobZ29p/8uL57mKwcJAnqluvFIJzlJw4Y0/j7Gmo2InUFwQBcUm1LjCBAnBrMJhx9ZKGf25AsQLi2B3xwIShlH8hNkNMqJk6ajg9CbiQVIpygPwNMiLXj3kC7ziXxXCMnovukhcxIgJ7QhR1mHFZCGKOk6ZOGa@wGBhrUF1h1zskIh7Q66Q3z/5kwh6HRcMxeuLxPrdiqIpGHY/Bf25UCk3aCZuyYDhTT5jENLgtwx5AgUNYscbHKJbgFSEkeN6FKL@oYRHy1Hut0yoGHV8IjkfCKG3pYy9kBuPsmeMbVfZm4pAKhpCYRPwFKffUuUJUalqu5pNUO4DYCJxyOG5RfPt7R3XkzjhrRvR9HucmNg5UAMR1kwaHpH0Xdfjy06tcSSCvcifQRxcOlTQT4AX6pyIuwWNnpmeCHEuN0EcexwJKiaUJCo76bUn5BtuyPOBJejB8A4fi41ALzIlMZ@r4wTrJZkIccFKOWMYME2II69Vv6ieDofQcJZtXPHCC4Chmby7O5MaaJEHNDUw7VGZbRe22JARXme9OcMtcI3kjSJiFKpmkoT@y5gCXaGpsGcqH3/0Drp2x5YP5B4F5mt0G228Htj6Yfyf0UVWw/bPIpoHth9z2UsEmu6mSbpbPSLvAylOIgJwPhRsFQ8IQqvWlAkVNjs39@f4h87qoLRYbdKRP59oKyUwopzBzBJhxRg2N4DyFWTvO4kk1Pwc8AeQCJEEeB9kaSs9wT1KonayqKJhxXNyQae@iMeX7CUhZ2ZsJKukETkwpFop5VYFMSmdhhKQ/ZYBHqXiEolgFwhg7M8f1V50u29jYYILX1S2jXqxxBFES@suc8CrKaAJgY1xaaDIIA0FmIcCvEQRLJfS0KmJQHM2SahIJW8/h@AYsYYoMACKisx1qXACe0wmqCpDZNqY@sU0XoRQEVNt25rTzhhFJEBGPG1VJXu@Ts@NROCM310vl@WYQvkCwIwSrCsswtvmStfyWfRKoFGWAfT9dgr82mP/JEj2jHLNQo8xNBZep6@opsTTs4ZHt4MTmHuSWpTRFyylqUZzDUCGICvKL/f0dRAk9HChG1zBfO2Nva2d3/7ODw6Mbio4IMnkdLMmSjY10S5IzzZPIkIzyvVip23vK0dPtvbAq53M1m1pEiNle0evZXJba9ZyuSP0LfhLtZtrkcSMhNXvfiGkjlrRHe65vxj7zVeYAd/hBmBuppsTLq@bJRqNlx28k/26Z8tq4vI7IBaaWR6prk9eziVmMFNUfo6J6Tw6PWat4xhoP3/nO6ezEduAw58HBw1iAAsRkJYRaRTwhAwd8BmimWkTjmvI9In18lohUikY5moM8DnXqY9eaacILVMANdW9omZ0YDOA9VIvIFbiEGkoi1S@yN7ZMPyXGaAqkjmwQELFUoFl/Wp3KtCKaIgW2FFeG3aZVLoxPjEEngPiShxNvyA6d8dzc1iMjND0HboQ9mvDlMoN9NhkBXJ9ezw0ksQbwJxIEhopKRlnlUjX0rECp3DSNivsgvSaqlgsKLo96hdRUlIfGtGcOgICnxAz09E9UYKuiY@9YaFI0ZyeBxvEa/hQPIM1X6UfpFpzOItebumzaPWOaQmU51RPgT9E9ef7FWVIUbuAAKTjcCVWiXdN0GHZE3Q96xExL4LXOVonU6V9TRVmpoMIhPMEPzQIpHvnuEzDC@JTqj/QxS01IBafHZEbWVCtlZzzfFZnU4Fo8bJZOk1QNL/IArhlB@2QixGEpnIdMKXVoHXT17B6@3ppj1lRl@QTMlIjIEjijtgNDOc5FiTGQkiBIlaKtY9uyKuaIY6/MMQ/CoH@MdIIx1EO5xJs0R9KEs4N1QaVmjQdzupRmPZDXaqVSDVpjkdRUGKDFTSovKxDtEhIScqlQv8GBbKg11KyOKvhxPh7IwsNvGrZtQAUBzox0GIP1CSCZK2bCT2lkZpq4KYU4z@Lj4IQ3ZHRRQ/du8tLCRduEUqPJmdoVjKmvWjio9oNh9UL5HxVZqV2mElb9QgFGR2ykEsO6ms6tp9MJez2VsHGof/AA53SuEsBJtGUQkaYAJCUssQb4DJxHPWHXEvpGKtGra@sUAqwgpF1CgPeeIl8m9Csl8QBG6gy4uLzzphIeKXnMyrJ6BfnDHpJQMoAzl6gTj76jgcknzHQa8yAn2piB90rrKE00u3Wk0PRRLeBGlcEo6G7XqGrUEje@IsIrMHAOGhoIu4aEPdhY3w6BZ/q5c8v8VvAePOFv4tklRtslDW@e/RcWfe5PWAJ6lyT9W1ylJteyCRU4TUElojWjiyIQk1//Oq4WmZBKbBZzZ@lkIVuDh1orsQL7JNHS8nEWfwjiurIuuMJl61H5jBl9rfhGkpp6X35zcnh6ePil2Eol4zsHLwU1D6AlVqH7vleJaSsu9nFXPL6uxOLKuvqgpCivXr0CdheuZkNuzEPJJ2JTSp40UyWwNEql9UyxvJ55mGxTVsSUpolHzDQV1jLHXq8HtzOkr9mk4vxim5uYFhjgzwK30bTP3WaZ4SCBaxg29LoLrqoX4qxV0vX1dF57aNdkLav98hdrV5nLw/bGL787Uow1fB3g6wdXT9F8pBY@WVv7ZHs7n89A5XHz4VeH397a2so/yhQOm4XNvJRd2/irv1hb07QNTVk78Tz1JNk8/VLQsnlB/uXPk4eH32p7HrYfXjmmghGfZbhVViiwU/YWrtM@wz@Z3/bmzDqaO/23OEACs1wnYpNMFnLJo5dJLO7buKqq8Qv6taka1pja2Cz9lx8dvIn78YamfOHC24@/iRfLcW4EA9hyoe0s3ohvIFjxKn6h1Ot1MJb@y7@D8I3PIB70udiAR6MQxlW8iDekOgV5F28UwaBqGqT7/3znO7F4Y4qI0NjfY1pDW@e4opYfqA/YlF@sFVfL@YOH4BxeoVd0MUVVtVbYnnPNjU0bOQ@h8NCuzJlzi9o9xIw4C7CBDB8Dhx8@Kq49fPWIbTRgqMWrWn0YoZrCSmXBcaA718D2JHJ/Lktwye3QXkOrFBQhXq5n2jz5CFfjc4ZrBY6eLCh7ZP9IuF28/vr/@usf//WP6Pdjuv9TLB5uaZCaZ42TRngxoYH0iQW2pzZ7yi/bhj/coRVd0AFMNpuVJR5vNPBB/8BGJnpfcwt8GpGFIGZBboELaAalG4u/hzZB7GNnjYWLNRQWmakIPNdkeDpXslnZEAU24VqDH/3hiqz4XCOXwJlAbl5rrHHbdSv1jcWb8ebJSZU60/0vtjzu@FksLgFpSKefA88YIPN9rhdwy3I7sEVIHY/F/0GvRozFL@E6SUtXV035ZbpWC/7AStUiG17cBHk6uZKkjZeNdLpJeWs2gkxuSCcNmbV5funxcgPiTW80N@rODt1yG@tISuadZNF5ePKy0dxYjCOI5uHDNHbmhxBPI3HCgImHmr3auGpcNTeurjY24L9Bz6vgDa5XGzf@9JpdtRVA0XV1go3eaiqNltIKGvQE7LLSQBdZaYGhAW@AazZj8UtEF9Y8IbVgdampFgsnEqMusV5Fv67HWFVd13JKYfpJcVeLxTVBUNbR6x0OTMBeVGJxZNIrnFevkMOrD1//H3i3Pnz9b8AKOcPPr5Fv5w3@nrzF3xsff8dd/D1/g7/jt/h77uPv0MPf0w7@YvE6Y8AbJTazVvYsq56qp2AwWRZY02F2qPZwLMgaLHuRvWDZkaP2wGTALwsmM9tn2QHL2llbVcETDD7L@mjqw2sAvz7E4sLPzGYx8uwZg1QsHGFImy6937WZ2Io1WfKVAUyNrMpZuWi2TwrF8Ztm8qQWV1othXN5TMvXSHvy1RVrt3efPWq3FcT71lPnYPY/OBjNW2/9jw6cpwfOyIH/wcHBU2jl9MO09BCueiO9Ebw2443aZqsqIfLKARrHlY3NViMnobmYBpTU0C39kdcsRng31loxEIG/@OK89sUX@D8/q53XyBBZwdCuRQABGDeAI3eACL6o1ciAZrjOKFayofH8i1Zk4gbli3Nw@oIBUx79lQXbP8Df/P/X/@kLlmqeiID@l1cbKbpE/Ini5dXlVfBsiKlUYEltwA8dwI5BLq8aaCSgSzA1U@KJeHXF3eCZEjd4hA1MY6NBgWeAQCLiUZqULn@k/mHfmDa/WkngikBaTQVLba3WNJsVax1wiebb9Xe0aiPWaD9LooMrbSChqSJBFPK1mrrOzVpeq9XygaVUrtXKgTmRSlVuXo3splosVrV8XhRrtWwAC8JYLTRCFIand2vYvWtxETPL@3wqizN@9MWEpFAVHjxIBd/Y2ByPQTZXK9l37yKndrtnuu02uufevRPaAm59qVcKYM@W370DcpMUQWp/5vBF15Sksk@0BqVQAXFcy5fAm6mKNktzqHu677upt@Y4I@A@OU8QSctxNuu4reSvfvjd77aSddwMQa55FSPAVFhhY6OYbzSKeTAXy1BwIcF316QG6YoqXiUUgRcXpO5kPPBSyyWRXK@S6M/iG2yzAf3Uw4tdXsWp/Vi@IKY6F4Z4CS6hm1qpcEeWL6bK6Urwq6@JrLHOgl@z2cyl8@ul9YcnJyfXmHykpbVLva5e1S/1Kk4JXdW6gRp9PLqiP3iQq0AtlrO1VqzdfrR1vNXGL/DhgjeMdwwdiSrHcDFz7CabNH9XqJw0sUQnrWSyWntI7a2WCyyerAVwUhIIPCtXqOBxz4uZfTzDNoVYMV64g9d6fMzUUg5G0diYdh2VsqyHC7cuc/r9NXCE5mIdXGP3DMsKPzpw7rhW79zsGWux@OGTrZ3d44y2AQOytre1k9GOXmzHVbQWZnbyzqH9@e7Wo4MXEODwye7W0e6n@5/vvjgEdy/2@q1uGLoxMYzz9mRy/gb10httYwyus6ttdE1Pf/1aH9PFapwYn59/@On3P/z0f/rwsx9@@Nn3P/zsx7/6@sffh/uP4f4hf//w31YK@PzV1//sjz784c/A8T/B/R/h/sWvvv797/Cb7H8O91/Ouf15cM/B8ZtV4411vAALylo5vQ6j3XqlAphArhsxSOu3f/X1j37@q69/5ydw/4vg/snN@3d/sfz@8fdW3xjuR390O8wP/x3cf8LjCmF/@IfcDd834P@Qw/3OTz783r/n/78Kfmj82Yff@3N8BJZ/@pO/@ssP3/0Pmlb@q3/94fs//PC9H3343nc/fO8HH773j7UPv/@v1ez8448@/PhP/@uf/cl//bP/hf5/TM8/uc//w0/@6d/8n3/zf//NnwX3L@D@92D6xd/8B0Djv/vTn@L/R3/6d//xp/j/3//l3/3p//p3v/2vyPAH3PD//ot/y59/@93v/@33/vnffvfrFc/v3/r8@h7uX/93cLl/Pu8Tz33K9bEuX/9G@flvqY1ZKoAD9IEApgFDu31hsBqLZVk2eEAn/PE/@fD7vwW4/XsACbb/GWzw5xbw@gFZvvxywS9NsxpS@ssvQRz8MhALv5wH@gFj7xTgubMP3wHAl@TLLxZBQaL/G0IBGAugQrCFxAkEd0xy5199/c9/ju5RSHT9rfn4sqHrHGwCgd@FRfwBduaoGPOwP0By8OGn3/nw83/84ad/8OGnv41jgZSvZLYyMIDfPmcKgIV7wCFg8T5wAKiiSAiy@1pMA8PaBs7xxdT0q1fQCGtgApFqPVbIgS2mNsisohkCgqS/TpFM0zgtAvc0lq@ADQzgNCUDeKXBazuNH4NOx6Z18CNQ/Io0Q2OjjPNzOGlQh3gxEA@TaZdBXmHTbYoFQtbTz1l7vT7lAdPo0KAYGGYInZ4Lqiaky/VHkGB9@ohhXBh5OvYK3q/qjXJ92sDo3lMWII70NiQJUPiR6vS08R7sdYoT4GPTR@8hK@V6Ot0og0udikqpZdqUplqgwlHZ04zKje6M4a7FzYeMfSKoZYHPakBVsgAan@kZ9CZN@m2Cfyu9HhSH/qGR7nUMD@00pfrhbtx/E50pfAAA8UoSbnaDW5IwNw/Be8qjSlOy8ErzGKDm0nxSlEUOxKCkY2lq3zRZIH3Iw8dcG3xwxuiwOIlEAkwbDSEntA9ATGTuadXzdReX4ohZrDKhWBHQGfcN8R2RiUOSJtcfrcNThf/uGu0CppLU1mOJJM5JJFmYkpTOOXknzgsRlpBs61SANAGyT8AH74cPwQw1RO@ZWyw@C8cFDFp1ZWoxz8RYir54JNLEh4FMEIs99QbbzhSY@4wgZNQirqaIfFok9m2nWq2/V/OlGLzJPsFvLQVf/YHGwi9OyxsbWOmNS4kmaNAIjGEx1mgEy8ZMjTWOdo8B/PiAqVpWZiAKXOZLWr6QL2i5YrFQ0tR8sZIvFso5IGXFbEHT1Eo@XylXSldUlodADTLV9U5ho/GPblz/wz9adi13xSvW@JJNZZp9voo1rDrfupjA5WOhlRVqNFNENZdoZjP403I5eEIeM2qhdLK2Zl1KWOQW7Ze7xAV6yGbsUsLZ7m/AxWLfiLFvgBNckAYuoLFgy8P@QS1Y3sbPJfIlbkEtAO6IsRbgDo8NGvHy8nLujsXXvvrKZ40GMPXS/l4sDjg/ZOF6rmT25KFMHznsTVyDfAeMPdr/fP9o/@CZ/Gj/CHjtb@NRGjkWv7q66kerEGQ12MHBQQyJDYhNORXDX3XZZDIh3w7Yr6Z6bDx/1cYxTZO0nJRTJTWH/zsMGv7vD6/BX8MnhMppMX4sysITJ@H8UyX2/v37KW0WqO7bfrBrQMuX0Z3FEOsfAEV/oHJjoTgzZtG4ERyKb8RocbQJGHcSwy9oNU9iG0rkeYz6CZ5B0wGu2@wJ7hH2HXbs8L2o20Z3BcTOkH8Lfsd1QIr6zWG2dfuUez0y@UHpyOuxjppSvZHpD1dAvBiP8JyY4f53i2F31IEM4jIJB9iGh2s5zjKAEntxuKKUTyO9JrgPgRSbAPjz/U8fH8@9j3e3dh7Himz74Nmja69CAFRgT3b3jiNrifuGQQtRFN/effLkujV4AQGtkdi8xgqlTAbGIXjgO0MXveXEyxBElVczKLqvg1DeZPmTGrAD5dqmitMkhYRSVw@foDxvOYcuUNoWSufvpY3P6w090QdaXd@WGuX36XyJlXPWZWN3iF@IdWuuMfUHxpo9YS@a0FVPUGMJ1BqeA5RjT3F7ZEXlZ31ML0ZH7vCrVPgFOj@GJ617@OVpnHHp4CegJ2O20hFe6IRG1xwMYQQ5d0KAWEfXGdwfe0H4eXkcqu9WB5@nQW43fKwl4Lgmb/ZZNiYThdAq5UK5ktPKmXKlnC@oxUIho2oZtVQuVYCaZ9WyWiwXKmqmnK/k8jDcgG@hUorFgQybfUWBoVQVBHhXIVq7ix9S2MAvUjjysBGL83ku9jali9DOkX3CBAPCCPhJL8@nHeDrZl3Q8ng8I6cyiFFnXRbf29vJ7u0JwjZacAJ@JysIPbQUytlsaVsQDPLZgSFREwSHhwEvAPO5JZvd3hGECY8A1bIIwhAtu0Xk8QXBRMvO1t4epvMaLRqGB7BT7sMtVmgpAZiNllyOhARBeBNFB3BbPKE85XQXLZgm@uxxnx3wE4RPw/xksxDDcw7HY3gclnVrSxD2uWVrC30@o4IXeFa/iZYtugTBBQsgoSAMwDBwDcMWhA4YERUFoQum7oUObvjRClTVYfu6IFzwCsIqEoQpQevdUwGY2cAdk3n8@LE@9HvGgF8XLn93IWvgY04nu3udTz/tDAYd92Jr99Pn6PPZZ4/11xcTtzPoBME6bbgcCAM@p6OL6xfkcb/d1q2lPt8EH/uaT/uibWDe2vobyFNwDTCRUfsz8PkMfKZLLh4bXCMA7eC1PYL3tt4hn/AiH3pPOx2hhojqX4wNnOLDPkOfps@M9K7r1NA@ra8lU8nMRbOYPamRMxulxMts7Qp9@yn6LCJSSPHyojmtZ09AwClpwRGSlNCaagVTyKyNNoHoVdf0TVXLp6dV1Lnr9JMsKambKfXB@tvUM3FTy@WrQmtzUxKa6smmpparxdLL9YkgiFV8buZK1bepbDLLGD7EZulks1SYC1EqpXVFq5ZKYu0KasKHYaoz8Y12O5U6N/RTUcS8Io8A@adisgsqolnrp6aZaZ1nil2ItWldrfHD4ix7I64eaiuZ4LfHeIwDiG66ma0iAU8JaqUsQPqKkhJFpEZIP@D96otw1Sd6zRkWjPySWVXiHy5Uy0VRxsMIbaffpo83sVfzkMhyx77Ak0N0ajjc4EfCiVeNHSOHjgOAzlAjUge/lUqHxkFA5Bp2GJ//UEuVWKwRMKmH/LMxtcD66eMdGfjWwIZ6T@Q9/ES248r4aVd/wYfr5AidjmHAkh8buG2vG7rt8PO88u4URBA8s1C7lL6QruZDHAEvztPAIw01OuuOh4NRAYzZY3q9ASa9x1KUPtPFcypnu9Got@sjYzT2L0Ay4ivGUKow@LPJiG0zDosnjcJzFu36NlRAtmajEjQDrYlpfBpr9FDFy3Z9@3JSRRbzqmbU6QPgQhxPZ23a9Ynt6X3j0HDxYND@AQzdBp7A6Q5ftXYRcAcq@/JKarjMnhVi3@N1FB3zoAxdYoYCj3Y9e1Wbz3VKlxodsTaoNxH0HT42JEE4kaTmuxMQuGqxBvS@2kVcr3uTDv9KXrYDslaxNgU3tZSvDVmn3nk5rbn1MYgIrGZBLc5JPkyvEfw7CwbSttyuT2e1kas3NZB9splQGtJw11dGy1YymgojKYywEBLuEtjzcKtwg7@KslLKSgmMCZnsNCurGdVQMyBqvjJ7r8SM7@za0CLZahUbBhqVrPDWmZjW1q1Uz2H6hkRtDF28RhnXM0M2NuGRgnDPDd2iAKIosZT0ZrOYLmRFsfYGcu0mUj15W9zM13qpbdYWwQF4A7g1VszX@vXUS3GxjsVaak2se8Ybqk8kFVQZ4zVojkAe9CajZpatFdXMpdSWrizd8xNqSas2J4mmpEJps@8GG8JXDeEEmuaKxeA3v2oDrEcN3EKywJmVGbsxcxsjA2oZ0IpqRasFILFxQKRSQgq/oMw3maaSyZKWTIrJGs48rIF7QOSIIiWBPCYfqJsCsDtCVahoIGfOEbcbWeDCVRFEwKtYz/TGDMSs@GXs6vJqY37fzDfZxYWelkLrA8YG6USMKbSKLrfjbI1Mktyg6aGt@tbg@VYtgN7aicWrtElstqOHtYJTuZKy9rFL9@mNxkv@buEeFUg1Rkp/muwkkBW1HJS5N2eH8nmXMV6rfO@GspFuKK2YIFDf5guA5YLIc8rex0l/Ptu57AdEqfoUxU2W0qu8zzZPxPfPTOuynJMaJE@mWPx9GmoE97s1lPdxGBauqKLDXWXffKUVoOptJ3QA2dQH4gejSKEg4BSM8YqNjyovSy/LL5@@OHhxsMceZqvlanmuIVoPMxk1qSY32ENgXs3nuyC9vGNOQX1vf8Z32MVr8eo4mcsnc/PB6vFpPR8u7KbURkNSNzS2CRjKqkCX@mpRyr5rcHRrkEdRA58Pv/WT/HSjDHYNGMQq1GQhrTUa6romxscfvv43eGTrcvfzrScsiQfo//4vfq6V/v4v/iUtJiavauim5UpxgESjWizFLy/Hl5dXcHG/QvwkzvOUL4lg5ivcaryhBM5qSRXjnsRtkN1C3HsXaNRIadky@O0ccJtQhFqMV@KxePnpq3eMbYBY2egNBqZGJkVZENUSVRC/4M/e4zTWe2ntFVAVz0souOxZQeBw7mW90Wis0w7IZCONRw@1Ak35N69qJ3xuBKWRdZt@hreOP@Nl5LDueWAPbWBd3zBYoaEyEF8U5cNv/b6mFf/@L363Jb5rv2t/C@hspVIpqlr81zeveKCTSIO8GDbfBlvFQ7xSme/nR/L92uMfOA/PMtLHrYFPJi0zHn0h1TLtUwiAnAGY8bOpwEpU2T0PTsaCgfstnuQJzB3dM4r50OZdeLgHHWcN8SCjV1WUgekPJx06uXjsXuz7B3SuQwH8MX2HmzuW01FGOs490LeyPBClAAJVq09sBUZLPJZB3xJF7hVVVLRJ7RMUrdcGsDYWKyVWYwxSHuMx69a03xfofLZh9Y6MsU7qfcA/PMS630MwVP5Ep7/Dg8cLnFV06phq3GDJHb75XqLj4w4xNF4yPHBIVctItYWBx0EEPAAdHGOiffWCjDb8PLQQ7qkHiL6D@l9DePqC9CxA9EHpWQgsI2pfCfiH@nyJWJrKnw4zgfPK3IHyMbMGic4cKCHKjcvMjO4OSLGZjaqhIK0UNKuMei6bavUkwznOukr1TefcTVTeA2w8anOhkmCFkrbPvukC06aW5/S8EMtGIefLka4HOQFA3iB4rhu1euEpBafzmrQgBSonEP/k0C846o@qw0jBECC@HWi4Zecd0ycAGOAIAEMqAzz/w6sos4CqnckAD1ZgX5Add6CYnjcxCqVynjKk42ntEBSY3AVQTQnUbiuUOTwcHZWi4g@ZZZwZFqkfCLKN@p103ikJz3A3Dap0RFa9KBLqQFUulBRqIVXJcLdHu3tPto53H2WYpBYQHE@3dZ0INjVXudw7Tf59a@INAzTCILz7yp1iniN5ysskHypJMcj6w/lqT89nOIwAv46FE4XjVLJOwVxjhJ8i4xGzsd5DWpWhMHYyOMGPR@f5CTHTw6xMXAvxJqzcsOfH4wKiNKYVRxT0/B6ECr7zDmGwYAGHAzYgPDeAVtIKqIGAurV9wEjUT0KYKyw76g6EVZIaXAGDsGPhtwmTqEtrntomqe/oLHmMetFhiCfStpYkuoAqHob15CdestYF5j3kLNhZaiJeBiUw7T7mIsUr7tjZvgjbLzUJzt4IUCEisMdidBjnl3@ZBG4jis@zUr54eaa77G0dMJR6nMyJ@q5FZxxTSa4uF4K9lZEHCc681f1aFKDj9C5k1AZo93aGptVLvZ1PYwwMp9lPpdPdej0nXkKS7hiIkzcGYmigSCfW0K2/4AYW0pSTUlotG/Inr9vGOfvy6ZPH0OTPDTrS3nx5sp5QMsDgijUsgl5PIdCjg6eHuusZriiP8b0XCU8p/JpIkIgMrT3ymtkTyn1GwKIp2AuBcg4MPyi9t31xrA@e6SMjldST/DAZJmVCo5gbusylpJqZTotQRL1pnizUUV1YbFxBvBzUCWroGv1aByr6tHbl1c9SA7Hmw2s4n0QBkqhrGsXuQ6C6B49rtW7it8UfHz99Uk9u6AxjrS/pFcl0J0IOQBRCGDolv@W6@sUC6gBVIazy@XlQQhi40kmhsViWDUVvJIFxXZmfJw5psZBlOTlD4F5qkgkwzq3fbNKaO8OCi7FRRwc@tH26eyxkIKw7MUR0tHF4uyCixVUd1MM0OLohpaAh8OIIYer1/IMH5MbVnNTrWjYrAmrWriA2DzA3FQk/bu3K1eu9VFSR@thcolZBkzVFt71zVBEOLHC2UNp0XBgi6j3gIR94QELqqAb7zPQvHniAbfVQRcMDfta0vpZfLx@Y29/6snJUfJTqdj5ThYzw2nNsENTc8XwGXP1c5mwR0Fi3y7GLMoHqQru6MtZPHSXfy3bL2bJa6hmlglHO5srdgpGrdIBL7Pbz5U6vUtJLhW5HgcHNpyDyyMSvVwkc/THZ/v2SXcWYlUHw7/dV4N57hUq/omVzuXynXOhl8/l@WdVzuWJPK3cqndu5tll@UOgK6S6OHdcp8CermbvYDdoehBb/Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
# 
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1PLconsloPrs  \puts~-<V=>a$f 16=B->8~+47 83l{>Ehar Cr;rextge!nu U[d 2]persngtalle.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8           \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3           \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Recently TIO has been unable to test all the languages in 60 sec, so I added this line to the test driver:

```sh
if (( $a <= 230 )); then continue; fi
```

Tested in two runs: on first run `$a <= 0`, on second run `$a <= 230` (skip already tested langs).

---

Retina 1 code is on line 233: `` K`250 ``.

Constant stage `K` is used to set result to "250" (see [list of all stages](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#stage-type) and [about constant stages](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#constant-stages-k)). Replace stages below don't change it.
Note: Constant stage doesn't have a second parameter, so lines below it have different layout for Retina 1 – even lines are "bad" (must be valid regexes), odd lines are "good".
So `` #8M`| `` line is a substitution string for a replace stage in Retina 1.
Also note that there is no match stage (`M`) in Retina 1.

Retina 0 doesn't have constant stages (see [Retina 0 stages](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d#stage-type-selection)), so it is executed as before.

The state of `` ` `` comment is restored on line 235: `` #ce` `` (for Pip).

Golf of line 21:

````
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/

[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
````

It is possible because 05AB1E does not execute this line anymore. Space after `[` is for Zsh. Spaces before `__END__`/`exit` are for CSL/Fission.
`"`→`'` fixes this line for Retina 1.

Comment: I noticed dc has been disbaled in the test driver since answer 201, what is the reason behind that? It seems to be failing currently.

Comment: @Potato44 dc got updated on TIO and new version exits with code 1 even on simple programs: https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/UrKDw/38A. I test it locally with old version.

Answer (score 5):

## 272. Klein 010, 12930 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet     /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];#min=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers95 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}Vngt=Bk:pext se>ExPrdisps94 Cr ~-<u Uithw;re-  8hardoc""?2:body t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJ  ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<ne9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ss#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEAQIsPl5m/eymxySffveC6LRBaBAVBOoQlcVSKDZvDEz3pjVWAqvPJ5VjEZr3ZG88kprR1jrsC05LIUjpFeHwk/6AS2/bCg2NP9g9pyTWYUCCJDs0ShiH7ZIVOXHyZOZJzNPnvw62TC8zi9@EcOHHTnd0XnX8Zlvej5rudal6Wpsa8SeGJaXyy5LEkJtuueDnmn7XlGKMZ0x27xi@3bTaoEb850L07bemS74ZRnru865a/SY3zF8sFgQiu2Y3fe99z5rOr2eYbc8gFxm7MgAz/agecGMhue7RtO3HBu8Vhh7YXeNXqNlMIAw3b5r@oQ@xwBF84LCTPrkGXvmuJ6J0TdNz3PQcZWxdbPX90cVsBQAwnAt52Dz@adTgdcY@9SAlPW75nAqLXqGvbRMtzUVQtfZF6d7e9OuWfa56ths73b69GX2wvWMrjGNf4VtDnxn3592z7HNc9M2WFZb07LTnnm25Rq3gqwy1zRabatrapbdZCrrmN2@6TJ0YW3HhSLzzW4hU8jUN8chtSaGLYw9p9CWg4cZ7rkHns6lCUYTSqJvmS3Wdp0eM2zvCmLS1zJjeES7NlkdmpBAqGjsjQehWybzbKvfN33uCdk1XfKGmFnXsi8kXvuOXKc1aFr2OcCZQNf@wKc8eVITglVYX9RhDQ0sRlTgYJCEE6dnRsvCg8oLqfb6ZtNqW01OHHPom7YH@fU0ZkHZXVndLmuZXQgwxt5MMc9hAy/i1OgaHa2pSUhcjIX1LrrMYs1@n3EvyAYkaS9TYGbPeWOxd@Df7Xhs2O8xz@qBt9902m3TZO/MfgeCs15LajkSg6fZn8pZaFs0AcY2IXfbR18B3Xwkp92GpLVYIwIH6aA0U44N2wHyucw2erw2NPsjyj2gCUO0HUdD95ZjenbcZ1eOe8EaZtPAbGNknnneNgZdiNFqY3FAPbA81nPgC4VoM0gWBPaRFogbI5NmZgSjCYrX7EPDxOJ1sLpAWQelfOUaUD9cT5Sjb/Wgdlh@3GOm4VnIsSCIZ9otqhn9kJc5kNtoobNLCxoekGLgEm7PdKnqE16GuQCURlhXlSvX8qFGYC422ZFpuOzUNc0Er6em1zT6WEujUUJkDsbgY0Y0qpjr6/Hdw704VFAeQjP6UCHd5dPvfCYZTCuzxXoJfmVZLkm7z3fY9eIZmjnPhErcdxUjwcrfMC99dmbCb6g30ufujQRYJaBKl6Wdvp821D4kUPUhgWkDjWhSL7NavxuJmK1PlUGk2XCoFpQGMAH2RYpy1hy4LnL3MVGNC8h017HPgZ6QWXdg8yLPZ6AIoP61vBQzL02sA7yMnCui8GkHagj8A2iEs/AOhwgKXQ40RUHRIF7P6Q4IDkJ6PrZHoAoERYz7bfYFaxtWF4OAP6LiqXZNDyonhhnYLSz5nmWbLY0FySCu40JbvIToDEBKDtAaehHeQokCYCgIh7KKXh9@83da5@eAZ7PZdNyWqK5fQGVvUtdoUGKhc2NYYR3b6FKyAC6FsfPgEMGl0bVaxOUMeySioERQrFfOoNti1FCvLGhyHQOYrQkMoumbvJI7Ax/SmGI944JzRIvXXMh4z2hAwVIEFDdlW2VPtqGUmtDMqc6ovYHfLjC1v8viXvqVslFUNhbOTEhcQkssLabT5yWocNoSOYEtflfN@WJzoqvwfMNzrJbUH/kdx84ytcnkZtnpm7YSn8ART8XdRjyhIadWEiWr3NTalt1S4utQFysQcTxRapabVatYK00Fj0YJaK4QDTZXU2kmZGQ11Cgu0z0QLjTgZF@owhTxc7w6khy9tYgzEmba7ZI7xEh0wXrpYAUBPqR5XdPsKxlNTyCbQLiZ@UaPWTmdwiEyXLRqyXgsnoxmnTBATicyio311HKQbXX7HZQ3gCi21wee62LdbRpQezzs1HwQ6VKsQfWaekLgLMQTr8w4cO0GMNKgHlGT5E0Ow6vIKAWGcROabMlmK9KQgQlAW/a9W9y466B0QGnCngdYh42RGudQNBCYZ2STZ4THRC6TWbqwgaEgtobJCmrDgkaAzQ14uqjzkbwB@HKWwwA23kgivKdnjLBX46LBuMFgn2awHrAHd8SaJvIcYD4m71AwkgG1Pw/kXua0WUbN5nKTbexWE/Pd9Kb6NTDpd@k7WxJmPtqYkNGwNojZXcM@HxjnwC8cG4IYzabZ9wWjgpx4PrCi6f6GHFXReWpeR1p8Mh03dSKBeDSOA5k8Lz3RFRrIXYTYroJMhqIfHwuwluUCW4KefCp2ALicilx@jSATCXgtz0lCIAFAJTOHZnPgA1eDCnzVsZodqLOYOpvzRd4JTUcPTtHYgbOr7TBqTIxeeZyVtHTohMmYi0LFEr2NBzpXRFWZcKDCjzrcjdnwejMQO2ESoSOIuGppQ4O6dw/OnmM7M5ACIUO0CDLpw8sBJLETFIqh4wrELmqsoaQcFhGUGXANaPlQ/zq@3/eK0E9YfmfQ0KCmpE/d0b5/aGNlSfvuyPIdbm50nQawZQ/aZzqIId0cNKzhVIbILSzDN550CQJY22Nl6LnfDqDWKfG2BwyT3LcROOIlE@MmFPwtAyABaUAope0RK94DpnIyspuKPFEp5RSTse3KCTBgwJA0n6HwNpnMN@A0nUoEiyZGSyNU2nObZFAjMimiR3BKlvRoImsPTKP0SJbh1Ta6nglfe9DtonVgcy6ncFkhwa6lR4@AtSkUndXrd62m5de5L3v8WMgUbAHGeCg2tVFmSkCYR2IwrQFDARjR/XBozXdOSNhVEpCRRzcTEZuu67g8Xr/jOleMHBBMihJ12@khd2cvSeBCCRqGtZaNw3vRl1JXaswUIcI@leTleFx741i2ch1fWFiIF@MV6DEXFjbAtI6mDTQlwbRBJpVMCKehiUKkyIS@VQqBbrX4TTXAPEzUsDkMsbd/Z/UVo1osLtdSRlUX3yx@E0Bn6DEAWsUP4IknymU0JhJy5QoyqjXak7nfxl7vpOlafUGEz4xLg9sFFZaJDFBwjosDgxIKL3fTpFd2QbqAwUCzo7jxs2rmrHZ2fdZKnt3EUxg6UTLKDcgUxKf0tHPXGYAYkqiuFFW9lkhUl0H4aJTjmfiSohRUGMbBSCTxSSGRNDi1lbgJvaFydhYHogr6VJsdl/ANU9lEIiQVpAMFHpC1lbh2XYD4G4laIhmHsIl4CoZu5XgcKNNEIniUaWxLEwQ6PP6cE2Y7mZSoecOoFH@3ulNww0HvZPCjwbt3yLs4jkZYw7oDg0t5fQGQ3rcDWA09pwatgVejzZCPTsTxqdPmo6JtfO0e7EnmkErr08O93eMyRdMxvAuQKdRzhE2DrAxUcVsacIPuoGVKs2CAbYCpOU4Jzh1g5OfNJlMdRmBqkyci0l002RxswGtI8HSY2u1NZsHrQHq3J/JASMidQt4lvzSDJHHwmWkKo9wDjr19cjAxRda7AHmCNb0uCt@qyzMA1vQSd2zRJxxjFNk@jdFsEDChboF82QrnAmzHVpEXBsM5JxoRnxABCHJDaQslCWsCBhG3rSEMiWM4nyJEf5RYUfrfdmwYnJraS@KGMgNGjrNVpjZT/j/igpTW9MatEyR9MPa7RhP4/SS6M5mdAULgQOn0bJ9E6Rbi6cEBjePvyyOIUk3DRvq1LBqnDiyvg@SFsQT2Am4bqIqDVJzcIartsyZIuedAaXNo@XzUCi38BIM8NTwlgeOkTT7OwFqGMjImKpi5IwHWacII3wRZGX35dAnbtS8t17GRyNouoAZWVMIymEI@i7xQjTY397M78@k7CzlQ7JazHqFtFOs0cZsetC7b6TrnDlsCAKyamsYr9r6NM5wwyvGNPrQo6x0RaPPcgaH@ZB00zXDONL8cjjcNhEwTvPYGegE2O9NjgDl5Ptn/ehfEED2XyUD6A1uGnjCTESzTeUTHJhsDiFWALtYbLMmvzX5n5E5UJ88R8yY@TR5Sw@QzWQaIkJAq0cLfUdBoI@cu0M4Dr1ZgmpX3XRoT4ORddFw9kfsJaYU3G8hhbMoZXQNSTCC9VeDj8kXGdZae4FvhVIHa7jm@kf5CAxaNLwklZNVispeOL8TTqopvmbxYtsLSLfMyjVxqjHm4azZn4h6aZjONvti5scAwkzyB5xzSnMFj0wuyyb8BDcKQ0/k/TyaRsVPqwrh5oqGTP@0MTMlsdhwmn8EQI5ozGTqIDoyVVaA8CIA4LgmDiRUhyXcGMKxrmV2rZ/n7NGfftXHsohHz1pBrCd9t4DdjBEeWCQI5n3AYdzI4rz7uo@xzDn8MnJywwhBf4yR1zVZ6aYztmeO4MK70mE5zCtmQ9D3hkXa8fkvzh4CAh9ql/t0L@vnnhzu79aPN06fl9MBz012rATyiZdZ7MJjtQnOY82DacIZwF@qOZTs9C3IUoHx30T12HJ8LD7hw8LAnhgEDHAc79YP9rePN469E4qhHt3qDroFpLC5OAYQ4TgjmTjRNp@GAbGEP5mIC4eJw6/AgwPLZi4P9zfrO7tHhaQTNm0HXMvRhun9xPi9DnyEI07UMJ/1htzW5okPD1IlZBMFscMxVYjA2ZaoKbxXdeKQ4KtPQA0Vk7B5VFWeBDZzndllWz6yttRpGoWDmW82VldW20W61VrJ6Idcu5LK5DLxW82sme0/gqmoOaeYGTHxWBCeQMA5IPH10bSWQcGAo2gSJZTQzXaHvHYlr5nLm6sqasdZcW1szsqutZSNbWDXN/Gp7JZMx83qm3SjoheU7ExdJBopWY1uPZoCg1eFkAXkC81PgM9EceOJB1rtirWw2m2/m2mvL2VYus9JqrGVyhVZDXzUaa2amvbKsZ/VWM6sXg7A4owpcogMFhlKlDaJp4KXq4JmQgs40WsS0yhgsQwuGs7iMLKYfLCPjwEF4rKDHQCwi49SscM@he7CEjFM0wj2P7j1cQB5LsmQNHQVggQBxHVlzG4HjGjqGK8gTa6vAKgX/nOU/P5DAfK1nbhD5Fa5BR/J3revkfum32xPOWXK@ULEr646dl8mZr0BPrv2KzN7ymgkc4lshfHzleia@W14zgUN8OY4PV7xno5vymQUaIssTMlwhn4lrymMGYIhplTBFV9XHfgXym7ekLuKa6T03UIh7jXDz1fL6G75aUReL5VibeQM5BUnswAH5@cDCefv2RIuRwhH4mSQH0wiTE0ljn@x4mYSpl7PXd@QoIs4MLPvCoYFzaKpnND2HWEIUvYvu7ZBtGGrQawL0VqJu@/D@q9do02sGAHa60zNz5EHTnqLrh67WSB/TBydAZ6Vgcip3IvqG2R7AKCjdsGw03wOmrhUIst1oWPNAgRK4@SD4zgArsuMBjESz2oqmB8NeXDoBns3nYU/3DwmwYdAgbnL@n00Q3x@4PoQS3//63RYUwu0i6hgjGguGhrptXlH9aM8tMREULfSaXbrjXp8IQ6b7UDYNXHI1uqFhNmoqfVXtGG4Ph1yiuKGC4gtqwh11jaecz8UE39mRFBkReXKdgdlWjzVnQBPs1JIIj4wG2V3HaBEZ@FDYMimQi4XNi8Ec8kFhROCBnmdeRDNWLth4q4DfGfgD/sbdAfcVo9XH311NVEBmckZDN0FENhqWeUehu8bFoOWoIOlRljFh@Rmw49zTZJ3a7hoX3FhH4@zs8wy61vk5yBPiOw/sqgNjGxqUpq/oc1@98OyB11cbUFg@NByyUVPo3RGD2@XveSCW2D8XGuZTzerS6wGFHlYuqi4g0hGhcUuTGiGaNUXmrtEY4VC98/G1DCMkAQd4TrmZTGaWsdsL136jW5Hmh8e@ksKvrc0OzTdTcZLMGl6l@SYqlU8gU57Ftqp7ChY6LqtndNVsK2Kcy9GDqeOxaQYozduoza7hQdXyRXGYl1B89LqrumPP1IRhlzs23VHZx8kJtgDMW00WbEu06qbTtTxs2t15HHR6AW4cJ25no1dkStqaRdgWyUxeRw1Ns/mC0/RxKXdORXsAl@OrqLhOHak5mjOPaE3nCn9zRYuOc2ny9@yO7t3MVD2AY6ldqhJWc2aP0mreV1NxOxC9ZtPxYma6/GZ3pvtkGwimOKIDtAfWa8/qOh47ofddZDl3IRh/z67RUQpahq3SelDUPDuYSFSfaWKWdU65Gt1zp5svnKcNeM0t/IHbxj5BfB/K/ULupev3c69APnJsXXznsv2LtHtxX9nR0oSLi/YR4x098CwWJhYl52cQRhK4E2d25vYyBQqppfl4eV4BuM3OlTEKvr9EzzKPukHP0h@RvA3iHwZYK4DBd7kM/svEtnJ3bK2HsadbaFfvy0SkcC@6JnRk9L5VpCyb0T8yhJ7JPJxZtbsDc2DO5FWHjTcm7m@/YxTy8ERlRDYWxWwnzgjhXGcI9U6MHx@UauzD0XYngzG6FjTyeyWdmfyuDzJ6H4fcR2A4QsPtgOf2oD9RuBOjOPv4bsp1@kHLdloTiUSfj@VIhfvlqQlB3jPpd@fgig8GcW2rvJLJZIR8E5m/nrDcNehaDsO@sfh7ImJyGcc8hsXZEDdinB3HeCoVit668FSc1HwYd8rOmxEg4LW1tG3Zpj/C97wimcVtG47T/ZgiBKbbslB@A6kUF37uK8pbspHYDcbGcx8ezpw02vNmPXiHJEanQD0ceN9VG6JTrw8qZhWXrKGVnk9Z754Hikzk3hcLdPM0ucS3TnTnC55iRkXXCtrqnS2Si7NOw@wa/DPMr9yFb01bvhNfKLIIOZnWtnA9jK@AjVdUY1N8qz8CYlktGOR0zJ5J1jtGB0brzcALPnOBhg7@ZnhrtN44L1zfAkZh43titS0iSvmODcMy33DPTRzXdHFVXLjOY87BrPpM4u73jHOTn6u6i3uOpzpw6zAfDY6Nsyc9inzXWROC8a0fd1cFaEwX5sgLvjMRPhs1oTwHvfun6qbafZM2Kt3X0LX0zMWEe2RFu@N07I7Z4TuBQtu85gE10ucn4u7KBKT/vNNkxJ@iu5SilO063e5DKIv8kXNLx2nPTNMuntNqQdCPwjsyGuAhPvdOAUJfTwSiTn9eu@mYA@iyPMd3@qZKtnmgXZws4u95XDRY3PllZ6HunCEAigTfXxb/vWPTc8Px@3361PvdgUcvCqrS8bpZRblH0TykVlg@33bE66157jSaHeu@JDVMw7eti3QwI8Std45s@xEqWEzdQWetawHx3JGGtaEc9T/Bz/68IhWTS7zbCg2zy7jItgeuO0JK@I7DvK5zNeYPk/snwmlcvvqAhnkpECuDM7xJGsCddcEOsjuWQMRC4twKRkI4CtyqmQGBRZ87ozSxvTPSOpaX@WueXDSVf0pUZP32Y6ZExbYHmhy0IjO34D5RfyYWo2d2VnZncO7dZnd8wr4FIha@Zpb05jmeaZ4qaF6o0AMZtvjMo3e2m8bt2/CtQ8kNzDtXV3J3Lq8QnN5VDceCTx0@UIaDudNmXavv8TdT29mZAsPtJeTbUKPZw2ZRPi2zzddC0HSfpNdzXDxEBCKF2nRNr4lT6ciRufzEuY/tnANnVrtsDBzAzszC7VXrmcUf9njql8/NcwO3Vx5YuNOyO6NWANbpxev7kH5nYHjWdwaOb87EN72AfR@6Z8a51Xw6QfkAWUBRsQePfyaqPTrdJv5Vx/Lo/EZguGPOCSsZr7ZYz@og788arU1N14cHo@@eVokISmLvN1P3WbBHPDTgggH6GzPjmjUT7/Rp3Dgi012T8JZPM7PiO7NWzd4EcFf0V4Nef@CJz@zYaZ9OdIq6d0Hu3pUFbFF9C9yYdYyuP3saOzIzCzKX6CTHxnlS@NdW1zlnXxcyDEQ06LRRKJ9R4baguz4yfGgR9owKTHE/cKEUJz1Ul2fsLdQJc5mplm35d0/w@L4BY6Tgi5nhnQ2eQkwf4Ft78rEY1NPZFDm4U4KBvn3U7OKh@I8dCXC2C7XwhA6tozE8Nx@t9yIac1sgDHoX27yKjtfuXPQpYpfq2ANfxV3@d/Up@Tv7lCIbFvKRqsGU7@w@e5GI1hDa/nqfHGrCQHDgdUdj09yNB1MVz7JBWJvPiyehg9HEjkkqDY5po@Y9YTb7eHqKWP6OM2vEczSC3ufBQyboQAa9HbOJK4/3xv3ceQaiG3RlfWC6vWMTtwxM8ZLZATHYgdM0ukCf1r3RnBDaGX3FeHBt9M0GlG93bJoti81CvGP4xhzZiSYOaQQYmu6tK1a3YbpvaEYwYp43qJ1M0FNzSMOQ@RWGt0LVbza5wI3TchNtZHptx@s7js3fxIQz8NGf3c1soHug18NX3DXcvzzR@80cpE3m9vCSbzcxW/zg3rzsumbD6fI3ZmEOO7AtvrnAcC3TSx9Y9mBIbkwF2W32MIdv481oqzjN4XWgsV1ZMMYOd/fiZjW@VdibGkmBSHxpeLTkP3tMM7GT@OG7ijqG23Rw7UwYPnLlLHIk7B4@Hm6V5lsTGlAoQ2BoRnMQ6BW4J6ndXqNHr7ljkkhJH5sNPHLXoPOjvjGcJUROHh0TjlOHtwKWhg0/z5QjGPUk7u/IpodskxS3@vQihn41s5oE0T23zOY7I3EPLw1bEc0lpw0a0c5sSJOb4EDM6Zqq38E9lmnfn8cwnlsXg9YD1rqCBZRBz8Q168mVm7mVyvE6VCOc2av0IcN1TbF1G3cJQtMPzMh11c25VRbRw//h1mdp6Jjr@RU8wT8YqufAzu7fFwCJH7i2@Dyk2h05nt@2hod9VOPkuPP4C2YrB0Hgw5sDmpbmZQLK0x50@XzHeWRHV69F4zuQBtsOmLrEwn1TNe1LlVQcDYPlStcI9MjMLcPpzaH6PbtDr7xwPRA81L5H33TfO9o/ODzV@p5@x8whbvgbWF1c3aOkBG6QQTLNn6I@ob1qD1ysUOGDq3ETn5m4xapov2M0TN9IG3MHO@hr@rMlv6enzw6S45PLTNnuuE7PTES9t09OUpB29tnJTO9o6D2o4m1nODf4/q6uJ2bUwRc2rQnO43szYpqH6dSEISvUqKf8EO29UlPT6Zut01Hf/AK6ROS93gOjz8/N5HPj0jrHpsTW5hKKWhtb0/IrAcgXMBzHQ1F3j0s@t0CSBQm9Sd/EPdDHJA0s/9KL/tPiCcuIzQgfF0inQOJQF@mfCjWVeClx3BDcLFeoNPC0QJmaOJtJXW1wSggcjWZzgLOCQGONEaCiGMlkIiGJUE@dK9ZDTU0YyKMjxhdWv8QygRHp0QFpiuBRyYLCFg22Xmb6aoYlEiWurwSaHvCTgVlibStAvel51rkNSQhSQKqmUA0N12LlMRiy@QHeapUtXg@LmaJ@w8pMLsqsVuMpxoci2R32SU/UMQ9eXTRq5cW4qsYX42d2kWXiIbjZ9czZ4MYELCQWPyLBIX25DjmHFMCF1CxxNTsgQqAKq45ht6B6ieYI@Xe5shiuiegUt57/5R@2hGYv0mDXszyjCwRB5XzAGTrO1QaPNyBXv2@gZjDEcdXBZQWMXd3eZN4VLhFwhV5QXC/2TgtCTZDQBAiWIz5xHKaC1xxcvcYjzz6vGDw14fFVEXEYKsgUjKUHPRuE15bf8TR2YtFp5oE7Pp8k9CPavotLVK0U22ctE3f50iF1WpHtOs4FHVzDlPzlH3LlSHRUXRwhDqInpWiRGPFEuk4aiZpNZwCpDpC8M11HgChIZKPpD3D/A@nkI/cEHuAmrU1Q29VAZxFFwxUXbW@eMHWXxVHbH@oYKVltZXHz@NMvqpla@RvWS5v/9bvpxLUgnPyJupb35BQLQEo3WLGi3jnwHvvGmbw4lHmE4Tl@S3CqK14eqKmQVzI8yh/UMcfpB80Gh1@kZi2sjUJ9iYJmKudAeVGPVNZRhTWvSHkRHRi1UR4glYkeNDCwJgg1b3XlRWXAl@TVE5/lIEJUAGWAiSu5o5PtqIgHgywO2XtGfTbwKj2XARsnZBd1P/XKW8EZkOXo2Zz0jtkY0P70y6yWzZUpO4v18nqFTCDfOaiDrfrqbJjNqGfD1d0ajCgFUc/Ohp9ksl8C1R0XQj1OY8vbfb5zvahVMu/fe8aIyfJNvMTPEgGbWLw@2j/aPTndPH1xAqVwE7C2PX6iMOA1WIvokHDH6ZJ2O6ALDu0@gv@EtjEbRP2piYQUPc5JoILWsiovcmOENU2Evif4rPCeGfG/DSB4WttiUtgzQC0wqLIh1TDzgz7q6GMirNAzRrXMwv4DG1BIGDyxNYOXEqlkVgZiqUCsB5KKzc/sBnd7CMXuxXI32TZmgiDFwviqoT/P4kwS3PxK8t03PO/vn2@O5e58E8wd@QbQ0DUIs7e5f/DieHcyWNDJE9ctr@XEOWbOnLGl8eFhoFiN1IeIgLiloSwzmQJwq@jMuHpX078yIVuCOTZ7PDDVUEq/LI0rJlCmjBqGa0IKURRKAco3KIhMH7OGsVskiUEfHUF3zbMYMoE9OUQdJFyTBeYYacrV8AmygVgFuYKmd0RMXPDruBcVf1JBi8OsYR898Hibm9NVhb2Ox@A/0isFpmyNDZnozvQaU1kWfl3TPocMB7CJEu@j2CInhLzI0y6H6UUNp5Cm1huDVhHp@JA4ngy9dNfoe4EwGGPPHd8ssrcDh1SgBMwklC9Iua7BFRJT0XI1u6RaBYYvIGQH/Rbh2987KaN0xkUz4u/ROjewsaMCIK4bWCgp8F3Uoc1Pj3MlnZzkjtAHGXSVNBPnCf1voZTgsUvLs2AsQ4XQRhmnC5wScyMyjvqlSfkN2@x6IJO0oPsGCcXHrhaEE43OtPKDrarN5BjUSS0UGVNMlhDWK9/WDwhd6RUOrl7zwIsER5i9CM74@oKqAuXOLTtQJl1E7dI0CVVkvjvALauV@K0gQRKKZFI7fq8bAZyhKfXMTH/4zd/h2lHPfDD/UJiHmS2w/bqwtcH8G4GProPtn4W2LNh@xG2v0lhkt1VCjtMZaveYewoYKucT@VbGkDEEarUpQ2GRY3F/sX/EvCZqa8YC7cEQeVxWyGaCcQqzelAzLqmgEZzHMC7HMR6liuNNqFxQSVDGQbGG4jPdmoLaAYvpNCYcFxc12jtsDvl@HlIW@HaASnJBEkvnc/kVPQ2JVC8DhKS/6ByPMnKEiUQRGKN0afXLrxtNtr6@zmSvaXTNcr7EK0h60Xi1LL8OE7oIsBIfLVQZhIEg4xDgVxHBlEUjqScwKPZmcT2OjK3l8PoGIqFCBgBJoLMdaDwBmdMRpILKbJtDn8SmUTAKAq5tOxHt2AEiFRBx3KjKdbpNjo8n4ox4pJVq0WKQXyIYTQkV5Vk1tvqKnflndk2o9GVQ@342o/7aYP4nM/T88pqFGp1uK5hVptXDYm7YkxPbwYWFPUgtU7Lp7HJazyciNVQWqCC92N7fA0po4cAxmqb1xul7m9u7@58dHp3cUjRGkPFpsDiLV9aTZ6qWqtZCQzxM9yRRt/bSJ8@29gJSRlM1ntpHiPFe7elkzoptOqVzYn/JT4Lejps8bkWkZx6KmOYF1T0683Ab@9g3HQHc5gfRbsWqJK5vqrX1ypkduxX9@1nKo2PaElYuMJ15pDo6Pp1MTGJ4UcQpXhThaYGaAx11HODhV9@5GGtMEA4RDw4eYAEOIGnpAGoe84QEHPIZoLFqnyy/qcIj1sdniUilb5iiCORpcKcFNq2xJkqhgrFjeJ2u1ZCgA2@hWlKuQCnQEBSqXtK8ftfylYREUyBlFIOAiSniZothcajRjgSFFEgTrhS7S6tjgC8hQSMAfPGjgddhR04/Mre1YwamY5BG2M6AL1eb7LNBD@Da9Dk2kcWaIJ@oEBgIFQ@TykfV0LKEUsdhEhVnQnxVVO0oMq71WjllmNA65rBlnQMDVxIpaOmf6CBWhWonMNOk6NGOA4/jFP4UDwBGSfpRuj2HY@RG1dAsu2UOFVRWVayBfIru8auXl/GEfKsOkILR7UAl4ZSm0aAhGr5oEWMtnVONbS28zmJKFezaGir8Qg0aUCwQ44nvHoAR@iel3TP6TBmQClyPaYysyplipzzfTTC1wrXo2CyZpFE1fMgDpGYEbZOJKg5TcB5SSZehdNDVs1v4eWf1WVXXtBqYKZIEW8QZtW3oynEuKiHBKAmCFAltGcuWFTFFvPZqvOZBGPSXSCcfQz2wM7xJcyvNeTtIC8o1qzyO6DIbt0BO1bW1oiiNSVazxqBa3ObyWhrQzmAhgZQK9BUKEYBqeLMBXoGB62HAFp58btq2CQSCOtMzoA82BlDJ3EQquMomNdaETzHEeBKfCg0LkNBJDfm78esubppYTJdocqZ0A33q6zPsVNuiWx2l/8e0li5dK4vd8igNgk6ioix2ynpyeSmZXLSXlEUbu/rHj3FO52YRJIm6BkOkIQCpi91ECeozSB7lRbu0aKwri61ydolCgBUGadcQ4BsvrV0vGjfpxcfQU6fAxeWNV1n0SMlqRtP0G0gftpDFdArqzDXqpKR7bDD6RSuZxDRoi3VMwDfps5Mk8eyzkzRNH5WENJo@74nmNsVVw5K4dYsPJ6BwFgUNjD2LjF0cbKkHwGP9@Muz/ObIHjziz3FFgNF2ZdOLiv/ypM/DGYvgd3HSf8dV2nItt0DAoQJERGvKSCSAmfziFzE9z2RlcSO/3L1MxnOZErz00irLsU8Wz7IrMRZ7Yhg@DNnTS9dnO4XzS2a2s/m3qlq12trb2tHF0dGXw1HiTInHtg9fyfoKgK6yNfo99Fll2TkP@7gnFltKS7H0kv54NZ1@/fo1iLz4VCtaJQDRaomqGq9VlVXh0Kusri6l8oWl1PGTeB3SAtlNKNls4oRZVpqdWX2v1YKf06FbpZQYf9jGBsYHBvhnwq03bJNxuGmenw92jRF3t2ID/Oz5Iuyzr1@@fImGl/Swd8cifIxjFOhixbqRi1Eis5nsX/7pwk3q@qi@/pff66XNBfwc4ueHN8/QfKLnPllY@GRra2UlBYTj5qOvj77a3Nxc2Unljqq5jRU1s7D@F3@@sJDNrmfTCzXP02vx6sWXcjazImt/@fvx@tHRdzwPyw6fZaaDEd8F@Oksl2MX7B08F22G/2R@14qYDTQ32u@wgwRhuUzMJh7PLcdPXsWxfN7FdF2PjeivTllbYHplY/W//fjwbcyPVbLply58/djbWL4Q40YwgG05sF3GKrF1BMvfxEbpcrkMxtX/9m8hfOUzwIM@o3V4VXIBrvwoVlHLFOR9rJIHg57NQrz/93e/K8UqQ0hEpbK/x7KV7JKoJnrhsf6YTLbfAQHjLKYXVg6fkNUynxxmc9l1NNsm3sYDo1Ea8ep69oyJwtNFEWJ2dXxzB9YBM5apE2MB6LjMWVCj2MsY1Q@oIFRHuFk4ULXhDi@n4V6eGcbSanIl@8QuvYw8E5Zf/XOMl57lF5683kmn1yvQz@NTLD45q4tGlmarBdlxnuDUX4kdCNcSvoaOqjoADr8zclTxEeSLFcqpOidR0MYCHza2sahTTFCShc3pl4Dbxeev/v1f/eSvfkx/P6Hff5ZiwZYmtXpZqwQP1B@54srXZ8JqP2PP@GPb8A@/wIou6AAmW8xMxsKnUsEX/Qsbmeg75SZ8KqGFIMZB5sKxgF9RvFLsm3SaYQtgl0FmniwUFwrFfDGbrgfZo2zwlJPhWSR34/yJ/GzAswB/9A9PaMX3ArkIZwK5/SywykOemR2AFKvGqrUab9OVaAHd/RxrWOk0YatHu5RLKaYCl0omj6GSMlG34TlL3vO8gJ@m1YUtrY2xxqTYr/ypSCx2DU8tqd7cVLVXyVJJ/IN0Vwpt@HATJK12o6rrryrJZJWSWK2ItMZXnHjeebKuslqFZ4DeWv3VOqBPrlfXy842/TSqI2rtVaW6PokDnnW1VnnyJImkfQIIKos1BuMKKI2b9ZvKTXX95mZ9Hf7X6X0jvuB6s37rnz7jZw7M2L@G5X9WTVfO0qJRVmpg19IVdNHSZ2CowBfgqtWqFLvGqsOqNdIUWFarej5XUxm1kCXgXumivpRdTueGn@R3s8AEPATPynJ6CQ3vsbMEcWdNiuHAYY2PH9bI4fWHb/9P/J19@PZfgxXShlcykm/jLf4dvMO/tz7@nTbx7/gt/rHTd/h37OPfswb@HXn4d/oW/zYb@Hfawz8pVmYMRLjFjUw3c5nRL/QLMFgsAxJ0J9PRW9D7sIzJMqPMiGV6jt4Ckwl/GTBZmTbLnLOMnbF1HTzB4LOMj6Y2fM7hrw1YXPizMhlEnrlkEEsX@zRSuk3f93WWOJOqLP7aBLlL07WMlrfqtVy@/7Yar5Vi6bOzNBdGWXalRErWb24Yq9d3n@/U62lsEGfPnMPx/@FhL2q987936Dw7dHoO/B8eHj47A55WST5Jqk/gKVeS6@KzEauUNs6KKlbmoFrH0usbZ5VlFc35JNTULLolP/IZY4RvZeFMgsH6y5dXJep4S1eXpasSGUIrN9QFgADjBghVEh02uEC4s5dp6mSv4LkkvGRD4xV4BiZuSL@8OkOREgYQ4T@QI2r9Ffxb/9/6f/aCKdVaAhrB9c26Qk8C/xKJ65vrG/GuJBRFWJR1@EMHsGOQ65sKGgnoGkxVJVFL3NxwN3griXWOsIJxrFco8BgQmEcsjJPi5S/lV/vFuPlzFgfJCYbWilgXPDsbZjKJUgNcwsUB4z0tMSVKtPlmsYHLgjCc1BMEkVsplfQlbs6uZEulFWFZLZRKBWFeVJS1208ls6HnQTxYWUkkSqWMgIWBYykwAgrTM5olbOSlWAITy1u@ksHpSbpeJS4X5cePFXEhz0a/n3j8WF/LvH8fOtXrLcut19F9@f17uS7jPp3yWg7smcL798B04gnHVZ47fIVYUXX2SbZCMaw5LuRqFbyZns6O4@wYnuH7rvLO6qdk3FTryQlSiZ7JOO5Z/Oc/@t73zuJl3LlBris6IsBYWG59Pb9SqeRXwJwvQMblRb4VSDlPrumJm8W0zLPL5MV4THjphdUEud7E0Z/F1tlGBRqqhw@7volR@bGVXEJpjMzENbgEbvraGndkK3mlkFwTf@WFBKssMfEHPddycmVpdelJDUSe2w8y1dK1UY6n0/Gb8rVRxGmsm1JTXL2Bx92Mx4@X14CYhUzpTKrXdzZPN@t4aycu0kOHyNCROLSEC7B9N16lOcfcWq2KGaudxePF0hMqdr2QY7F4ScCpceD2rLBG@Y95nmS18dzrkLBO/ZZifaavLkNPCx2t1Kf9UqsZ1sIlZ5c57fYCOELZsQbuDvDMbje4ruTKcbutK6tlLkixo4PN7d3TVBakllh2b3M7lT15sRXT0Zob29GbxZbR4Xh3c@fwBYQ4OtjdPNn9dP@L3RdH4O5Jb94ZpmmYA9O8qg8GV2/xSguzbvbBdfzUzablGW/eGH16YODCmfOHn/3gw8/@pw@/96MPv/eDD7/3k59/@5MfwO8P4fcj/v3Rv1nL4fvn3/6zP/jwu78Hjv8Zfv8Jfn/6829/@7v8R/Y/g99/ibj9mfhF4PhPAly//vNvf/z7P//2N34Kv38hfj@9/fvNP539@8n35/8w3I//4G6YH/1b@P0RxxXA/uh3uRt@b8H/Lof7jZ9@@K1/x///Qvyh8fc@/Naf4UtY/ulP/@K/fPjef8hmC3/xrz784Ecfvv/jD9//3ofv//DD9/9x9sNv/ys9E339wYef/PF//5M/@u9/8r/Q/x/S@48e8v/hp//0r/@vv/6Pf/0n4ven8Pt3YPrTv/4PUFP/9o9/hv8//uO//U8/w///41/@7R//r3/76/87GX6HG/6ff/Fv@PtvvveDv/n@P/@b73075/2DO9/fPsD9238Al4en8yF4HpKvj3X59pdKz9@HGuNYoA7Q1SEsCzLs1sikCYxPhkXpExarLOEDLLlayBaSSyB@Lq2tAV@ukfs6gjAJ2ulP/smH3/41qP6/BcjA9j@DDf65Bbx@SBb25ZcTnixJkyJq8ssv0VMMI7@MQv0QHN6nQRjPPHkPEF@SN39YCAbx/m8EBnBMgAVwkwkgGNzzyd1//u0//33yCMOi869NoMwEzlHoRQR/H2T1h9jux7mJQv8QWceHn333w@//4w8/@50PP/t17BrUlbXUZgp69rtnfQEw9wA4BMw/BA4AdRxGwrB/QcqCYWEdZyolPfn6NaR@AUww4lqScstgk/QKmXU0Q8Ak2AjJcJjEN/xLK2sMLeAyJFf4siR4bSXxSvmkNCyDH4HiXfQMjZUCOA1xuqEMeDEQD5OqF2Asw4ZbhAVClpPHrL5UHvKASXSoEAasNhI6Hct6Vk4WyjsQYXm4wxAXIk9Kr@H7ulwplIcVRPcNJQFwJLcgSoDCq@6Tw8o3YC8TToCXhjvfQFIK5WSyUgCXMmYySbGl6hSnnqPMUd6TjPKN7ozh3suNJ9BkZL0g8@kQICUT0PhOjqEREMDB/yy5JLJD/4GRfksYHsppSPThbtx/A50pvAAAvKqKW/bgp6qYmifgPeSokhQtfJIcA1AuSUJUgBIcSF5JSkkq3yRZIH5Iw8c968gqEB1mZ3FxEUzrFXlZrh/CEBLGau5F0fMNF5cUSY4sMjm/JqMz7n/iOzsXj2isubSzBG8d/ncXaDcz5aW0JC3GcSIjzpOWZJ8k@e/JkyX2CeSdvmM3ianJZWfFifFsrieTchairDhgW6IsJgkRTjTQf1J6FZNYjMoeGkuKv@Gjlck90pTI4VVZSo7tOP8oQmhaSkulxFejLzlowqCRr/hqiyQw8lEP0/MrdKaF7mtLsASVT9MkUUx65p1vOUMYcKRkOaXncSkqIeZtTotZbKvSbjED76@cYrH8jb6yKsGX7AO8Ok5cYga1pmO6pra@jtgr1yrNLqERBNa8VKmIVXimS5WT3VMAPz1kejajMRisXK@sZldyK7nscj6fW83qK/m1lXyusAx8NZ/JZbP62srKWmFt9Sak1RNgTaniUiO3XvlHt57/4R/Nema74iNVvmRDjSbUb6RKt8x3gy7iirx8lpFLNNNFpFysZlL4l11ehjekM6XnVmsLC91rFbN9RlsQr3HPAyRVulax23sED5MeSewROMEDceCaJBO7SPYPS2LHAN4Ay3cNyHoOqjGUwxnUY45O@v@fX90TY9fX15GfFFv4@mufVSowgFP396QYcLMOC/YbqFZL62h0CW5r4Jrke87Yzv4X@yf7h8@1nf0TGFF9xbLLGU2K3dzctMNVMrKa7PDwUMJuBEbKyzqGv2mywWBAvg2w3wwNqR99Sv2pR8pm1eyyuqyr@jL@32PI4v/D4bPwn8U3hFrOSvwUbRcPSAXzkGvIMqV1rhemgnc4OkarHF71y5TEdavccpp08KnULldrmge1u9TSGk5rpHn@CIbRLcvrd41ROd7oOs2LeOBp4eVPeKKxvJB20xpu/lbaiY1sfrW4gBsTyYUpbQZuOXR7FTgSWG6t2NKCqJ9BW4GQ2WI2n7tZF3rfKpBwTEAFo7sWqSjajm3e4I7fotGG/F43@U6ZopzNFeSbJz2zZRnsLIPHya5nguXz8k0ABxHhiBsnQ5Qe3rqC@8aLmbNMYk7YDISF9FGypHWhYaZCGx2qwO5qeBlltbYe6J6pSN98882Q9hYV921fbDLKrhTQnUk4wn8MotNjnRtz@bExg8ZT1BP0HEoEmLTNDvCsgO@wU4fvSd8ym3MgtjsG3c257Tqe9/eA2TLsC@61Y3GFJaHXUwM1lns9y@/MgXjR7@FRU9P9B8Ow22tAArECcYAteLldx5kFsMpeHM3J5bNQvxjuRyIFYwB@vP/p09PI93R3c/uplGdbh893pj45AZRjB7t7p6F1lfsGQXMhiq92Dw6mreID/X@JpqIWWG4V9yMHFujRY4ZvyKm6XK2VYkAYaK3@DYjKhVLLHmzojx/r6/n80QGQdC3H8mwFJOzl1UyxuJhm0CBKN19AFstbF8U@7nT2zMru8MjFVuWtrUC@2Tfq@oC9gMK4KrkmSI8FqB/QPmV5I1vEFsj8RekZboZe0/nJPsuT6IAt3gGJ9736Euo1aTlXNh1abHQHJhv02VxH@KATGl3rvOMz/8oJAKSGYTD4fewD4aNTWEC6Ox18Hge53fLpzgDH3TdWm2UkjRhsdq2QK6wtZwupwlphJafnc7mUnk3pq4XVNRA0MnpBzxdya3qqsLK2vALSEPjm1lalGAgIVjudBoFTl2X4FgGt3cRri9bx/idH61SkGJ8oZu8UIwFlH9oHTDYhjIwXaAKHxfMeS1ZZzq7gYaxlnQFGgzVZbG9vO7O3J8tbaMF1rO2MLLfQkitkMqtbsmySzzZIbFlZdniYAh7uln1uyWS2tmV5wBGgEjRZ7qBlN4@jYVm20LK9ubeH8bxBSxbDA9gF9@GWbmBZBTAbLcvLNJyW5bchOoDb5BGtUEp30YJxos8e99kGP1n@NEhPJgMYjjkcx/A0yOvmpizvc8vmJvp8RhnP8aR@jpZNemTZBQtUQlk@B8M5dgiy3AAjVkVZboKpOTLADa@IQsVYNrRCecQJhCSS5SFBG80LGQZ9wh2jefr0qdHxW@Y5f0Yu/0Kb2gcfazjY3Wt8@mnj/LzhjjZ3Pz1Gn88@e2q8GQ3cxnlDBGvU4XEgDPhc9EbTD6Rxv143ujN9Pgcfe8qnPqqbmLa68RbSJJ5zjKRX/wx8PgOfGZPtQ44Nnh6ANvDZ6sF3y2iQT/CQD32HjYZcworqj/omTo5jm7mwgRekekbTdUpoH5YXWFyJp0bVfKZWInfWU1jiGjgW@rcVuoYYB0wgWl@PqsNyplYellez4tCYIp8NszlLTi30NvS1XHHB2NCzK8lhEbXcO@04i6v6hqI/XnqnPAe5Y3mlKJ9tbKhyVa9tZPVCMb/6amkgy4kivjeWV4vvYFQVh6ETvhLV1drGai4SZHU1aaSzxVXcXZco3QBFfOiUGgPfrNcV5co0LhIJTDF29SBeUXbZiLJqldrKMDUs84SxUaI0LOslrqKFZW7haqGOsAHe@MkxngO64UamiAsUiqyvFWSIP51WEgnkSshH4Pv6ZbB@Gn4ihgkjfzRWVPl1wXohn9DwCFLdadfpykT2Ogo53n0gvcRTg6QxINjcSwN6ryid4nASuwMSrqwG3lNOuiaG0pBrt2N8hlFfXZOkihhNHfEr20rC@unTbQ0GWMKGOse0PZRZHVfDa9X9CR@uDytwOoXOTXtq4pbdZuC2zc/ya7tDGD2j4Bt4HIhzZJpQE6KdPi1dq3Vc5vjO6cXp6dfqTRTtCYwseULwzFOJ9Gig9gDU0Ga1mFGugMlogVhNqQQSJK6IHPVKpVwv98xe3x9BnoNwn3M9ymNE@x7PTHgWi4Jf4/lE4VEvZ27G8M8HPbbFgegQYxCsXt5CDRYlG/WbmmhdZMPYUKq0UH3bVnnrelBEefSmZJZN13VcOYYnPzfs8sD2jLZ5ZLp46HD/cJG1mYnH@5qd12e7CLmNcvWNWnGZPZEOxVArjcSkU8SKpFO@E1LkmrbN4zrcDYw6lFeJ0luwuYtMaWlbiY2VUkvZYvUEuGRet1@3WZblV0p0m4eCmIAdEOWQIkaiXPkcEHO8F8UiJERUiQvAiREtQolYLfIxEn3rpnReriL0e3ytq7JcU9Xq@5pUKUkV4C6lUcwoe4MGv3c309CzmXxpCG766kqpwxrlxqthyS33YVDJSl0odjHxwM8CGLgvHIgEeN69Vz782ncT62quzN1KhOt9FwSJulYvD8cFtFyuZlfyqWx@Bacp8svw01PZ5SzudE1lM2uprA7yBMgZEB5@q2BfgR/AgLiR1XEyQ@kqMmNyKjPMaHpKN/WUknlttV4nUhcKSIFEsETKd3ZtqDXggJUHqixZ4WskktmlrtJymLGuUv0FbleiTBqpDutbqQ6iOTaNLgdPqGx5SekuKgizeDro71ZrxeLusP8d9FLUtxv55Gom@S6RKCkLLFH2zLdEYWSMRIL@AtRmMUHDvEGvmlmATEP7U2@gpP1FfTVbrA4Wq6oOucu8P1@XK3INiuqGSfAXXeQFeasEbgEP5BLaWMYau/VRtu6aUKz6WrYkQKS@4MiKrJzJwbEVJR5fzcbjiXgJJyUXwF1wdGK/cegO4o/1DRlkPLkor2XBf8zIb6WAj8fzuhS7kVDkZjAyj11LN9c369Ftfp@z0chIqoH1MWPnyUWJpWn3jVaPsQUyqVqFpo43y5vnx5slAb25LcWKtBN1vFmQnQm9A0xNL3zsnp/keuUV/57hnjeIViK9glVWoyV808JhFPsCj2FtsDjky3B71Wx2uVbNrkJfDjw4AM1mIevetcTpzTeJpdeTFZY@k2SZuA/fUVDIJXgu2Dcxau9s@zqYrig@w9EzU4wib9/VWuKb51b3urCs8hG4wmLfsGRao42O9fQ3Megfb6gUgk2tn7/O5qBcbCdwgLG2D6wdutNcTk4wtvAEF7jk7GpW3qC1rWArwnoJ515fs/7J2qvVV4VXz14cvjjcY08yxUKxMLW4cvYkldLjenwdR3PvFxwcu31jf4bbgUuxfnx5JX5rPeasHBuWV4J9JIpeqaj6epZtQNVmRegO2npezbyv8HpaIY98Fnw@/NpPV4brBbBnQZwuAqFzyWyloi9lE7H@h2//NR5nvd79YvOAxVG5yN/9@e9nV//uz/8lbVqI35TQLbu8GgNINOr51dj1df/6@gYe7peL1WI8TSurCTDzDTV6rJIWzvqqnoh5akzMWa/mYt57oW1IyWYK4Ld9yG1yHkgc2z22cln9yTqSWb9FZiC0ba7FpFjh2ev3jK3DaLzSOj@3smRKp28RbrEI41b4x@HrOhgWXpcri2nPw0n4NYQPZgeXKpXKEi6QsXgliYe3s6TYoVK9KdWA7PjgEG/Jpj/TW8I/tL/iDkueB/bAG6y4RrJuslwFSncpnU5/@LXfzmbzf/fnv3mWeF9/X/8aOPfa2lpez8Z@Aem440RlMK6jySE8G4mGcDzI5lw4qjVlKYa30LYZhw9GhzgeRH0CXBsT2qRLFE@oEOpARgOEcYXAlvBcWIrEcjpEnihJUii7ktjtnjdThIMtoXZnaHLStfQIvaDTY2VgdtKjMSpw6KEap2bd6w7cPgmRCoXTayn2GIJADI9Q8ccCnWcTHFPVSyy9dDsoTzLXAURiCuuZnoe6v4ChS48gyAHUY7omivUNPBOJkJYNHFpDEEonebSqEHcN4u7yAHVyVSj3HCDFeOp4IBvkcukRHvAiuR36cmatA0CJJaRHQADIgyIQWzW2zpYT7NpKJktjVWE3uCkR9UQYwYkrCYMhthYeMwwClxDO4upABi6qyGKihJtm1DFAwnHw5bMyjCgwONlQFqJDlQ9GBbjocL1CWWOPH49TVS5brQSjHCF@1JSG6s3Gep1uRQDIguHYJ62inGJ2MomF/Wiy2gHFk5RcqHUqGcZAbTz6htYbSYL/B1darJFTRUUeJcyAKC/eKppAMgiMZOdl2CRdb9nVBAsT34S0NylRpDImHGOeDT/RSHNTkyfxRvpFLFCPKuF17pHBkKi300fuGPRnA7wwC/UJcGYgDtPxq1SQOe37QegwFGTF6hJ023JhWEHrgYHyGWVZT2CwduhC6aDNiNkVhvsEcwn8UCiERhUlBqr7EPEs0PQ36Unz@o5N@kHorDXupiStbZ7EtaHwZA/sK4M0ffFYaPNhJEVcfRrWfNLuZXMVZh4PiwuPDRfGyAFtUsw810gRTnaNKVwlH05P2iG6BAWiBMNg0kAaN7pmD5J0YpoMdVR4xXT6HGSRQYOUUjyzoF519izoNWwvLa7mSl9ZF1b6FDU7qk4b5FtxCDKG4osV6ocSmh9IvVvXujD5GFeZOMXqsWw@BfJjCig7/gFhi9jd40nVDHinOBT8VuGzyo2FVCTsgjJK3P4u6wtKHUv0Pde05OL1W5eGHaEvPe8lMTL1Rl5wRJ3OTIJdC1kutEx@Ti2OB9XCA5SSOEtfpnPeGs6q9xWQwoKTlWgEmdW8BAhVl7CPAabZDI58YiuG3D6iDoDaHrQs1OHiu0U8C11G7WZKE5qeYPA2@4QtZyXSdUfaAcRhfsCBRV@exA5@EBTz4fktKBiNT08AX4HW2WuBXwxVGvHqh@GD2o1m0mc0rt5sQaDDTofiKjPeLAJLLmLB1sG100HWF8AzDymckZIFRU4C2qSckDnqMPx0cF7bJeIlRXYbU4ohBkFqwIKiwpbhcd2cQgHL1dWVRjqABq6lmR6q4PXwWsF0/9wCIdZJ@2avL25PsfDqK3Gt39ikchXceAvlxpAuf1x7POJfSWrjqeS3A8s1lXjbi2MfeAm8sn/eIwULqPrAo3qzZ5FK6qZCa6qeqGbZWuo6qGZFrGZqIX6DSBhDNMPUKNVMAbJUo3mRal@1SsLjktodIIfCMgNHVM/nBpaeF5isfjuEcHza1xzYG92LptN1UPSQ@RTsOGqewwByFFiFvW8NIZBtXrFN1zVGCvknEBrrqTIi6YaNoHcnHzBCb8KuuRYra1gd1SaCD8Pg0HeFK6wuqleQru9GypWHof@Q@w/Bf8j9h@NIg2irwxqXvNDpBrODlRu1JQWQiGYUwNxw3WdjH8IMcjHTOQqEHE243cCvWabQAb25DcqxHFQMqBOkclBBXYfVs5rtmVdLtWT6HOq0TISAEgfU1RrR9KoVmpH63ctu3/EmnGxUJgSdj0g3OjU7ojbwuoJ5DAuIKganl4U6Z857Gp@I4f2@yDBgQHELPFEC2PQVK1EKtb2SJ1ScqjymMU9YVSSmRkKW8BJuIBVx0nPCRhHVIojQPcwSJBN8WNByhIJ1wQReungXbQCr0g0gpLY2XosDJaeaCmcpJSqkSKpUNUgmkB2l0vJ0VgJ/KIrqlFckmzei/KPJX/jo5LehXcxOPVVY3i@UpGhTMYeootMUzYWoyirlSLlCCtJLRtd0oYPa5WKo6JQhmqV0MJrg8WAWuGpZJVL4zQQvHzoyIttyMawKo3IZsjgq82bJ20VAUk7wMJgngo2CiiDCcwYCODIzg5ki2DAabFguc8bBhnOCXUUSOaREDnkQDj2ck8iaCAaDpFB5KRZPDXXWgUAlAz6d95aon1VmnnGJSnjZG9QxA4OnIM4xz6FaIOoQStJYz5q1mbFXI4mOMK0pBFgRbyFo8ftcitI0w9PV0BbyKE7KgEdxm6gGnFdABSMWXOJ6xJSwktFQF@R6OUn9ALRdOVmVZB33h9Ffhv/kVOAY/PTbjplJSH3SMZOa@vsHcawhZSMNNCJk6JkVZMg4YNkktSogllw5TJkhPIN7OriwN93oOo10z8ANGHizd3iNbyIYD5DixCd9xzd8Z2WlyAdBFtWvFwKcRe5S4GMA69x2YKgR1VNocb2KdhzVRzadc9vyzBReHMxFcJP2CXBl5VJU7hVGx5MkMVnIh6WImlcgFF3rdbx0ql5XPLPbThRDJaBo1bAexuMSjmfBFAkPfEggPewrDt6a7ifux4lKPEWwU6t5oRz2hWccItlkwKyaIM@DbwdEFeY545EgaddD0bjhK6TQveP0nHMQ71BzJoaeQr8/xo0JMvp9SkuKGThELUZUnVJzUJopIyGCfv7RQdnnWcVIhOGzkwgmiJFi7jSNkbLujOjqc6PjwYL4Tj4@vSfR9J7cnV4aVU@nmQ@1y9zz46JeVsYYAHCcjOX7k5ESiqpvJWciKaEzClA8wIOT2KINTi1M6SaAbgpwrQ31IxXaPFKfIxL@xTz6312AQfDdhxafgXfwnYyA3/RwH51ClxV4wRqiAuD7CeQ9t6MLq/bOA@MCWLxlYQ9lBZBXiXHZqJsJGmYfhtGeHK6hCMT31HncwHSr3tOupjL3nJEm9zLFLrLzi2in3jK7xshsKQIyFcEb5PgYRmbErx6WcWR0xPQcPqhToJNKRBU7I9E5UHFOlTFSlxG13rdgOIgV1h6a@aYU7s@nH/rfYs04ZVfms88g8MfjMdIATwr7@6P@iOu07PILYgQf5f0PL0k8OHs/QYAOYvtDahxt4i72eayEWXpAjxDCapNZJu1VQbfl9Pq3y/DjSHR/TqFwI4HKQSlPaN2eV@LWXSUeqRVBneQrPg@rkvdVugfXuUhV48jGLGz747qQW5hx20OzqUQxcpc7S8yxb/EEdKN5N3tOr1KfwVDDkMTpfIvG1SRfJCQcAu/DFyeQvoAvIjw3/TqvUEHecI5KXP7CyKdn9CNSi3ABaRywRKgY3K1AyYhASYEZwK9vwjibc@Ns3oqzORFn2AImo4wASc2JKEUpYPHcVQRds@3P4c7ohYNk@NzFtuGxHcPFaYnruBUvWikWv4wXgSHHzXhxVwGmHG/Fiztk8OLFEzJcxIufg2HctuLv48WgWSCAC1YyPEF3wcLR3owXt5XEjeTj9RdBvFq8GJYpwGxwK1EESIH5BqkRl8xsR2TTd03o2EioTDGsMV4Kx0k04ZKiXwb@uZ57fh8LeOKc5RIBsyTTJzqNSI/B44FuI9CAOqMlF0Vvvnu4R9uGxhcJgH8SBnPRMIQexPBYfJIZ8YShL61QwBcSiHyzODtFTJ@8beIByRGxQw2lQp6Mn6inkTzQUsi/CsC1xOQlBiJ8UF6TKHgBPiydGHheOm8lJ4iOUoRrrIkZyUKivo7fkSks66kbOnjpR0uI5q4ngfDOygCElxKhjfB0kOFosQ0j6zv9yUpCvrgZ0IqGodk33iix9k4FI64gWuYcb3IWOUPGEG38ibuyEwmHSZtgQehZzdR4Kwv7BeLF6DXmdRFJlTc@SEKE50ALN5sXJlbbHWEkOM5uUtRXzOuGgrA8SuJck2wSAmuoAWRg@Dz2cPC6i3pBPm74GoQc4qSKgggiIcNYOH91PkJ@d7j8HgjUARGmIpglWM/uSm@L13f2slMp746jvV2A6JliO4mZwlEYw5jkMDqISOZ31bVbIj5u4eBCPo80xD4l7QdkC8cE99BtemzBcaGU4F5OOl5kwfEiO59QtyWS7qUWCC0axiTw8IyHKR1n7e608ozPKmL0oYlso/vRBexOFnC08BAfZcCdIjlv5XiiE9e2xm2b1MuiC7JUvcg4I6flz7CYx47A7mkpNlyGBYfD@vHO4fODr6DTXV1dTYg@ejROH7ZanFQN@3GOmbYsh/3BjGFLNoXq1XHxGufd6Q7YhTNbvsVLOLMGYQCvlQmqn2jjCcHLIvx8qu1COA4boajAdTFuBsYEV0JRx8Au2xJ09YEgpq8sGQJJIN4CvVM0WkvgnCzUDryhrl6n7qtex81I9broxbBoghXuxC9iC@mB59Llm1z585Uk0elrtnPIXj7dPGWnT3fZ3ovtz9lXhy/Yy83np3h@@ejF1sH@NoPf7vOTXTaeUcAHL8TAASXQdcdsmr0GsOxsJrPCCPO20x9xvqNsJ7j7idFjT52mietR657Re9LhFs02/QoPtQvD0ZG4Rx4S2rN8n18m1wR0JNy06Ggb7vxnANuAMW0Px7w9p2W1LYCVcOzbt0wvOHrFuhaUIPDb4AhligtJeDkHbQWii9noTj28lA3gcZEG0Bje@BJAy@MBzJbGBOHC56MpeLp7/OyEbT7fYduHz3f2T/cPn5@wvcNjsB59tf/8U6Dn/snp8f7WC/QiwGeHO/t7@9ub5MATkNEYnlCnW/buSoKG4ESV5gUucdNluqEtOusMYCDBsyuDDvl5LD6wkftYRtd6Z7biJQmv7eEHC2lNgIWX5jHzLS5lBmu@tJ9AfuHRxTOLGbZOsUFjqUB7K4nmCt0eqgDHhYfeiOEFRGaJDo4rZB5fbESbclqWyeRt3HOCc9/8fDm15QA1RLQAuBFVsAGlzEiffjyeWieUFYit2XVQBxqPjW8KFBYM@iTYOlKSiGJi7wsixQMB@zbOB@ml0AHqPThkRbS@ywHYcujAAdgKd0BRdB/3grCcgBj4hwNkzyzPHd70@nu0/stWQ4ctg0axBZEmXm5UpAYbX9Jt9fpduhGBz/LQRUeG17QsCuIRPN4o0O0Gtw02TKjywBPF3VC4Vw0gZWA2bVxqENvY7AE1bPCF2oD7foy27zGlnNDYKW72MW2LXzVx3jVsvqVpvBWH6h4roO6Qsti@bYV3ONARi75DFRDvVZlMRxhuR0iF5kPDQcitWzEaYs8j3QMUbCm7LwFbtxLwy6ABROrESKdJPRUd8kQ0TltUZcVzoEbivO03UXiozq1B05wIENwF@cZ69y4hiJyaGCcF@w4pdVBEeG1miq9Zth0X2jix1R4eWEEu2Ow4fd/iZahM5mB8kxdAY8cGsb0uVyZio9s7p2K0HTsSaQNq8ZxYG1ApHxIr1Xi@SB6yr6Cth1eJ0T46TI7RcC7NyNpZCheRrkycfgFBmF@DiL0NXWsr5E9pzDu@oaspC@XKztaZ@s3rFF6EwNkCv/wr2ETIr7LsYVzQPGidjzYguih3iZYW3KbhDRoYWuypE9wSW3mADMaBHQvGdU/qpdCPbx@@7Y6nUabdyfH9@zIPpSJn4hx54HWUMXdLsWoQZYrC1JjY6xHhnZBY4PVK4JIinCG/foIHT7AUSkARG/kIXUI7eYuFYCFB7hqDNnAWcU@VKO4Qf4JVaOtEIEjSo0TLI/1K2SonK4n0eOcIi5BTCVh0KsCM11iN959Qf3UL3c7d6IB/Pxxd4c7U8e7ho7Dt3Into9KmJufj4t1SBNfD0X5zB1reuf1SaCHvqfmIeSd5G1tY08PKmVqMhbtj747x9a2yo7YHaLDvxRmUEGkktoFNS9SBolKFB0hE0YwFopPTnd3jYybz8QmEBb6HQ4aWYIOIe4Ff8sF3z1o2MTstFJrCwXIoPAUuE1vXwhMfdzTmmcSbwyqEDJIS9AiZxeSVmsT1RM9CIgTtpieGGFBuMnXXAQ/yqgLxDWqmBeYVG4thYQalmdmM8c7H8qKbugXdUlw2ju7Jpx3TvO/Gy7HcURRRdPOPcY4nRWaX30suHxeDeLiAZb4dUIZbIEnj/bAaO4GI@wCoaZMleEexBEWKm@a5gB0LaIc7vDKTEvbfv0JRReJCOJeFI2xdCMciaVw@XgzEHNp5iN2AgVs6hSffoQweAYsnl/VogSbGnZ4y2QWBkInXNj2J1goIXrsphTe9KuN@shwK5NG2tkipqQaprOHsrMBdmg/0Ce5tzk@zh@mogNveGZX6q4mK9xITMQU0n5mZwBMw53O55ftwT@ciCK7@fXHzPmSaf/q9Pozvxyi9kUfT@1Bz95@nAv9xBbiDdHyrfNBgpgKCqDOjT5nIO3VG0fRBWvi8ECQGdf82O3hJ1WSsCTacStts7LxHimInkFt5iDThMKO81dyi/s3d0SFDvje@hY@Pjzc2BMI9gje/CA/XRbStRJzwdOmkm@m6NoHxY0k9B4@P0WmkO8/M0aE5vqGVZwY9aZktmoG2OGTEt9WmgikGioRmFTW81A4n9UrTs3qqXormcG//YJctkVq69sQUpOzKiQjLWbDsuxJArJemI7DXoKN4n3hF@EEaUgFKIBMdylOINol700YUAWG5SpcqiG2fgqXq04Xe9pqGjao/UjLdB/0YAtLk6@7hXmLWhHqmNBEeEuf1bQVCpWRVkykouOE8LmKaRMFLE90j/ZSElwqIDZJ3XIFrpPVCJr8mUe7slJ/qVddqqaVmWWbQ5xp2zxu4V62Lc6dz2WZd1n/TGDZH794yllthy3jv1WOuflPPl/Fwq8JQr0iBrWWowooEbpAq0TOZMY20KOJ6MhsPv0sLLEEGGisX8QTEVC1lS72gFuJJOb/cq@ZrZbucKfWqdq2EZ/X8ZNlP6kkFHR5D5wmshS/IV/0adqW/iM62mvYlcweNEYySwrMfjM5@YP@OM1xizzbNl9M2Y@kRblbDMySabV4p4fXeWDMllH@kR3SIR8dD4jRdjLMtLQtSANRPgbDqDek9SkiPMtqg7zvkIyJSsQqx99Z76VFw6ihDEwYAUrVqQXLWCc8YRsF1H@464ruhVZ1LYzoedUxEUFQxJHE7@UyW8QggJlQcvarWJE8zjWYHE4EXOb6nYGx9nd/wfgPeNEmHOzUMlw4@ZGpoxPUN@PRpMQGjIMHco@MbEmQf7ToauAtNQfl03oU2ukskCKIPbuNm13QcicKvAwE44R9xkUoTM5hCsAI5kR/1o7kDVDo3Oa7HVQQ8BckL5RFmFnHz@Mpj5LTjm2iE0QoygfujKyQnpxU8IgeqTrZb2QjhExycSELL0MLmIS2pSMmrgp/uOJgSCaYGwQLgCCke3UsNnMiC0c8zE5rPiG2b3S4kmtPi0ZgcaKTjuCL@ZBi/V8U4a2Hiub96y1@d8Ne4P0/UGEqD/nsMVIwCybHrMdwNk8dgqVtxlRnJJhqUdFMDiWMMW7oL1tN8p26NgSthUfJaGXqsT3ioEZ9XM0qf@yxMhAkreOhf5f6ifmdFyYepnIB9Mhk/fiVRQCbtjRVbSaZqqWZb3Q3eOYU@WM1koCZjPDiWN1U73ijFkUnBTkBAw2l8araV8hhLUg84DrUZubL@RNaEMLGhTCeDHzq81bBmtJEIlSjOJBFuSOcLIR7yXoigIJxY0VjQcitB4JEIPIqgRaiFIFp@aPFWA4esTTfxMh5jfI@voLFPJi6Ai832fMRTPuSZ54eRJwlETHdBnk2mSW6Cxz64o8jUHb3IOO7RNMbZTOJ5ZJI3jNPkR6bbOMu9EPKJKKMIOMUtuoc@gtJjAD2ovvOKED1vpF@kl6RPDRCh@11zyDZxFGHQaSpp4jw6Kl31UEMSKWzxBv1@FxcVSbC7ohPPQntHNoerKWOMkWU0TdrHjTscPoUmcX4cAmnsEDFf4f6PsYc3OMfrpXHdBhUjAWvFCRXL16RNe8TnK6DNLGf5qXCTDTy@KAqD@fNoInjJ8daDlPb6RtPUJJDFPJByJJ7VNm/fYrocj4Wgji7o0oqS9J2B1bzY/hSXa1f1zLIeIdmlWO3NaMsr44NSQKTAI5sBcTWnr0hSZOm3yZd@VUSYYgfY0X8BddO8xEuMpU3oMQjQA@HUM91Ls6VJ0rEZrvEiXqzKuPCIx6adgdvkczcgW@Hlx3ja10vx1S6oYfjF/pmvBjdpKSwl4ZrUeDEZivrSaiEBgwMlbQcXf2k9Ak/1c3pgoJ7pA1GWEmwySbS0LNJCsksP55mAGqiWJLL0EJLBdnyrCSVDE1VSF1DxVY5xZPyq9khKIL5m18BDvtqsBODplzEFggQEK0V3pUESa@IflQYmMhYsoRtByaSB@znUVqC5m64F3HdMYCoVChZJOxTw6dP9E3ZyuHf6cvN4l4H56Pjwi/2d3R229RUtYeM6OCmGZU8PD4C7hIvlfFH8EBzkzRMIKZOHtPn8K7b75dHx7skJOzxm@8@ODvYBG6A/3nx@ur97kmL7z7cPXuzQ4jpgYM8PT9nB/rP9UwA7PUxRrEEwaRyOHe6xZ7vH20/Burm1f7B/@hXFuLd/@hwjw0X7TXa0eXy6v/3iYPOYHb04Pjo82WWYMWln/2T7YHP/2e6OBvFDnGz3i93np@zk6ebBwVRGD18@3z1mtAcgksutXUjl5hYMVTEmyufO/vHu9ilmaGzaBuJBAg9S7ORod3sfDbtf7kJ2No@/SgmkJ7vfeQFA4Ml2Np9tfgqZk5R7qALlsv3iePcZJhoocfJi6@R0//TF6S779PBwh2h9snv8xf727kmJSQeHJ0SwFye7KYbXR1HUgAOoBf5g3npxsk90239@Cn3GiyPczpCAQn4JhIFUbkLQHSIw7nLA3AKRDo@/QqxIByqAFHv5dBfcj5GmRK1NpAJumNg@jYJBhEDE/7e9K91u21jSv82naIO2CEjcrdUUlEiWlSgTx3diZ/FICgWSIIWEInkJ0CLtaM6Z@TEvMA8wjzI/5lHug8zU1o0GRFnKMknuPck5sUCg1@rq6qrq6q9f291UXzz/5PPjT55/8ew5fn6JxXxz/Oq5BwN2/AoTHGO8xRtgHaj0K@o1jhO0ix@BWQuac8s0nOr4SO0ffn2MLZfUwAGvjoVbiGzPPhWaw1yuFSxnSTRG30BwaTtQ@jdfvQ0R0fGm52W5L8YAHD17efgcVmSBkXLSD1/BqrOdQz6yv8FKYz7CzwzCTC/szAbtaNQf41lRk40dHJfxoIx3anhgnqvTwgeuVRE/CmUoFtvtr/fbYOi@are98n1yZppxVw7xcn8olSd9RNR3tLzRwfP0KdN9N0OovRXZx6Q4PNxfwJRM/RWObAsuQ0/Var1QsuEhfCxYu4hi3hVB1GgUjXSWEe@ZSKskDwT9joQdKKOri6922@gGxcBHSjSO4Z/Rj@kPXhysFyCd2a1Vq6ERS82I3oW6Gq6EoA3oH0EWiPpUZTUOwx8Gbt2uDm3@6mA87rmep/NQ2gTswIHr3ZG9Ew5y2Sv5/NRY2lUWWPlY292kwpjtZSGZknGpTqlnLv7TTuiPp1vD2A3oFKWqyBctzkl3hbNjwFFZCUQFnp6gQUad78X@t8ffoDVXb663cu8/Ne95bmE4ICLSwoJ3QvnO6M@nZ5wAJhhhagBJIkG6qNWsPDqcxCS@goQXmIhw92mtvghpXQeSgCI7C4Z2nbgaT6O53XqQw598uf/i4KujIxCd2Nr17Y2tzVbBoGR9W@a/b7AeQkolkLAJrOOgp9Ena5Y8A8WHZoqFrZ2yPzFwrYYJEb1cDxq9RLwGE5aRDVRCQYbdjfHSlRFG4Dkh0sFRBKTxsKD5denMFAZwM131sDeXwZxU/AB0JeIBiVUZLmjU5vgPlm2mv57ipkPCQMJihE8LnAvWBck950hHgpJxQzg7mKTqaD5m1DVDA3J1UXgsHp6lX8Lb1ijGHKmI85WGnXJCIx7mW6F02MSIZ/ZfCC9EHL0E9gVvvhV@g8c3gkdH6HRBnOwnr4CMRyYn@qNTp7N0@kRKPtvzYYhWVkxNuwq9@Z40iuaeuI0NwIc1G6gpZxgz6KtcwS2DB5KvkgJcPy556j1zKoJwYDkt4Vj5DZy7rDtSSkvjgMhvjS6huCwDVsJUuzJ1FHSSNwaPQpMzQ6ZfRA8q/3ekyZLyd8HihNJTalmYffeiJJXKtALzlYgSXekNBWsXI6Wm/epNWsy1PTAXpmOySzPn4zNAAhmdhX7xhlAK@@4SAiCTo2PDnr8m4uwiANPpY8eT7LgfMupeTlwla4VeKm6UW9k8K5PaVdZ7KPjDUx77mqwKP4es6mM23Do068Fkypny6nHscHGexvGorZIDxEx44tILDkrNc1ZdZpmWAwKZZC04PYN8BGrp9a27c6vKQrTMyH7Z4dKEgqL3sD03@0l45mPF0bdZgETGT39NoHUIqY1mMi4@gjDXoTjLYYjlPO6RMwRvf02ucIEYcumErJeWptzHFAeClaRBhSksIIpbrwqkpWX1yrSePJPIoab1X40YlT5kr5ZOUWX8DmmhfRq@ql4EC2jy8H7dZharrb4alzE0EStjt4Tkx5tuu@PxFFTHAPsNbSxHC6@qvhGnQziKZ1OBG4T1LJqKR0Ir/VANqk1svdMywxjo1LQ4SvAwQq9K/EFdugwxAJTRR@aVTeUC82oe3dNOx2i@1lDubvplF2hCKKJExF21qX78kVMxQQXhMyQKRrExLigkk@rBfQcz/a7G0x9w7UcVaNQLewZI1CqSfIE8SMcjgmTsJtz1yTgmjwYMBXpADCUa7EgzcaiwRm8JO0nYkpOCWSLUKPXkp9djmFQHQ0FFKeNK7cB8mxUYTKRSU5A8DbZno7lBTVlmcF3faowRuGd2e1o5pyMjUp6yEuE/1qojPrHcNE9v8Emc/P7jGGcPvMG9bFFBscGos@L@6U05R@1DYL5vonDas32ioMn0ggm638j0GY@IF7XrUOD7ukEShwuwALq1aF6jMtruZ@OLUfvZeBgMonEUgJ2GgOhzlnj4uKBHHLDBdHwV0wU69KFnJeot0meGj2E4Nfxt9iVbFsRWnIQT1w5HSKaL/QtGgSDPOcb4KbNeEX9P8lhnJs/6RpqpkD1eSuF2Da91a94njWWZeeceCxABt5eLlOAjogmdO7LOlrZuJOh8KIHVxo6qqMC7JSAv0@IdIBFtw2RarBtzI/zA7gRaZre2@KQ3L/cIS3CKOErhYYhX0MQuvS4HeH0qSJGPMCLgqWps162svIsyRzxBfFjcTu7m1u/cemjAL2h@48kyblnGCCTi@hpMKWZ7RUBBoS0U/ReRjCZJDFIsGsAqNMwU2p7nS81@XtxGDYrwAaVI4PJucCXOSBcMH7x6zW2DyGkvPFxUSqrkESwHqiD7iVu/nWHDu8JjafLjJi57zlAwPZOSXavRt5GqC1TC2zNz0bN2kxkC@e4Z02zed9RyBPSXRZRZ9z24jtZc6IBJxOsrbmuNpyCMnRz1JNSjFCfjSeme1LtVdixFWFtG667n3Rnny8zmw2K52iPS@gt8XLQK@fbkmCZLMYooAx5C85WeDZvniTj32zjf/PbiDjrcRrM0PsosKma8ezz3cVF8iwG7eqExU4rajmCjLfP@pA0db98uQaRMNq/aJDHaKDLaC360isqRyVDp/hQi7pO25@jRA8phvT2gnT0@txI1HwynoUv1pwxYJdITcdbxTCbIpUkfgy8QBY41XCOkjMI5Ly9oK69R6SBYMH7gAlErDiupH4o9uOlg5fiIwPz7bhujhRooieBpz45wMBj9hmAEoi/OHYl4aC8qjbMWlzQ3JYFVQak@VJI@Tg4/T9pzKuUGKWCKLyGF6dEN2XRx/1790r5AOiiBc9NnCeStl7EznlqD1sA/9qf2HHXgtCrJmZlR2YnQJtEAcwGslMEwZHMVtb9oyhyP0Q0yjcCA4Ncu/lmTHIi@vVk31MYs894Ck3hCbp5tnqrscZaUofg3kl@mIqu6ZLhCASG3GPL7DSgB4Ump9bgpQMg6NudlGipjBBn9Bk5LeEnopmk855LvSFRJsL5hpagvS7Fjl1FZWggoFsvTpA0BnWV5krQUWOiWtsVKsbW8P2kKUIg17zPFYShkVLI0NCPHBIRHaq2RKCcNVa4LB9PH9Q0v89HwN33dqVtf6/mvQB/TwpNKI/91u575mqm22cxmzeQEenh2rZmPQArPbrCRCr/sPzp5YkOXm5hQy8jIaBkShz1CU@oK7bbq97HapTPXWsfQ5dkHv7X51eYbUTLg6h8GUlcC09/65Z3Vgam6IYLsT6hz@iiLy/YgKawOrvTYKzR0NY6egR/QJu24r75@fXSUAXXtLHSc0WU43ajX68jDHRvDXodQoycpGteyqWv92XBYm1x9Nv26UyPRjxfTD@PxU21AhzAiMCfi6ng64HscsA2QFFNX5Jgqmvqzft@@MAE3KHHsYNQ4pWAdKFp/IhPz8vVr8v9QkbK@nmMHsX/nyky@q4D1TClF70JBbowIfuvozTMgD77oYxi22aiiwlAu62AmWLY8f@89LiB4DwkNFqEQe@/T6GTn03A4HJfVN@PpsIc4AA@u8xmOjuwMdU6CG4x0dncWE9psWYVvo6F1ahiT2KyOxel1Sd8KoeHdEeL@y3DwfD5xnZPvHFhVoMtr2M01hJkuK2fgeIL5fo9imQ@h2fdKfRlM3C7RKZ8YVnqZwOkTtOhJo7zU9Mkk8cglJjS7OzUSdXlzqwTFAF33SBXQkPQ0vNSTW5Ib4jqn80YfaVjnMqRNiKhyvxx4kOz3k4pvk37/fkKR0Px5YH9zgUhbADQDZfoBPREM@58qMK2PcnAhrN/gnRs35Q5maGOGQuFx1//rlbu/v68eTdbW1P7@ATxUKmr/YF8d4ouDA3UIvw/w94rf3Nhoscw99N7DywP98lodQBnk4FzrXkwP4Sd88/FUGAZr4xA/qvmPyq1HbX93rxXXTvYP8NA@PP3t3/7jb//@n7V9@fFf@OOAfpx8ZxJVq9Xao@77RyvXLfx9cnhWetQ5eTQ5Kw1ayGUo7r@axsEwsKJHq93CHSekesOoc9upKRM9E8UUqonhki784/tggf34Iz@dJunjNH1ETNQ0ezCcXASUXVEJe35pv7SyAk@7fulfSuQ7kfeBef8O3isPZTmBJhBp8d4ftf/q2fGxDTuOUp@0936IGDl406Xg5cjG1XlR3xNYOVHVqjqrqHPTPAzzaHPCbBPZzOTG/Ks0UveOYnJo71rMBtyUJtc3u@N5Y@oyHpB@p13nfPlZIJbK495T3kOjMtZA4GH6Fseqy7lX7D40F7e9/MpJY3PjrFIsFgvmQrR2l8Qc1TahuswFWXoLnfAZ@BjWBKYM9J0uqPORFlAgEqNYpOuyVrp8rZs7QtOaLCY2uIslS59HfxN1pGDEHHu4GUwBdSw0@OgKMhXP6BQG6gaL@@7hQQPoeN0uCS7F1yTHk7Ab9Rcm5AFvpEhrh7USj8ytqv6NE3PKmXYc6dfDflogEAS1AMLqwULzBTLxxpA2ImnHfdS/Qd24yVTnAv6t1mmATUDQZDxcDIZQmUuhVPEVSCegvCeDNRzpo3RYA@fshKD1hDKjecDSWF5sdydEV8SoiztkeD/UEDG5WOHj7V9Co4T5gBqO3A/Xx6Mg7nDEAUTjPjzCgo@n6HgLi9hwDZdUYSg0atE41vfLiRxYnXiemnBKpCr8TjffiT3IBUn2sFx0JzAhvBsz8SQnvt0VTpvg1X5oSAs2qCczyaG5YnbfQKu8xL1K3KcEomDKKt0lBqJhoc6Ho3PTf97djPE6wqqjq@RqmhyfABLLVKOPy1N1fBbAYecq3TyGO5xyU/Y4jqMOEAu6KMNEEIh8eGAKpZ6WClyZcAtuByKB8dXqxMwou3@alcL5hM7nc3sfoGt3pLkgkxA3SHFPLMS9O8Q4GIvIg1@j8ahCIrcTJlGXAyi59odaFk9wX5y2Kalht1cExkOA/TQDTDWcanQh2S6moU7LITrhYQWc/xdG9Q6IZuLmFREtB0egQYY5zOicpkRKSzScQAVkiSJtpPhvoeCDDGMOw0GUZPKUBYGBw865F9ea9DjJz7HBNnVzlMWDEnqn2YiEc6G3Ds1Awau/gaDd9uTw8zLe053BVY0vnjQ5uUt0nm77Jn8YeaSbY7caZjCQD6dvOTtCtLjiWkcgcgjl2cuyqkpH4YM1UOHSRJYXq3TAhwoQaZGnSeUEqNHMUQPEaW4apFK4nineYmBkbnslJxmVIy8PF6sEN4S35hfdUmSC64I50vP@/7vezFB2png@GSYfpEI@gDU6DTgxOBr5IpfOwKtQK@oCjgeicTpDRDoOZJEVBSFsIp6kVqWmHbmqdNdlhCukKU0IHwV@npTsscxl1f1Nc59lc1dKfKTrvT7Y5VqazsST817y9QEv5o3NDV0un9iirTf6da2PlsnJLBMwoUdHSE7La9BH8mBADN2xZAbnehlraBteS3ndZ9EsQLnMFE5l0RaNpLNjgpYQiWMV9mfJ@Dj59XV6wpaWvT7zkq5bBb0gADVYVITAq8kTPGL0sfdrmQUoByIQBBy/FsQhPBcKrHmIhem8iAcH47lbL586p065sbnjOWQnGz2s2I3BMip2Q0ZLwysbxfYkVEbya78NWYRPO1GvF440FitkldrMp7YUe4Lu/PdG3MV8w61DQjx0LFkeV2AQ6YXQmp4n02BwGdDjF@PX02BxDIsQ/Xw54vF8heV9CYsR3slEX77kObrfA1XDuUY7OeWJe3WRoqIC0Hy6CakGjMRnqQtLCBDeIADXafofZztrkcHuP/sujPZM6yYM6jlrKDEHUZ/zxsl5gS/8vcQbadv8DnjTtW4Elkf6lLumWnQE/KADhK23nINV/SHu9ISjzD6Ehg4WxuNrozlXWQ2BQeva5PpwV8YcD31uWh@fi2GTdC/al7NhEknPbnRL9wsz5e8@JnNSX1d9y/3H5DLM087qB5Z7EsEsTW0ZElQpFcQI06VY9qMmN/Wf3I6p0iCmCsN@NNeJP@rXrQ@MDWv3e9rUQFQOa8NGG6fYz4JlbkDuViFdZ5Xp9cOM8YHtAKJgM1YndPE0ieZre4xxhBE3hISJGdzfwmb/ezZy@Q3tNqRU0naphGeyDEttfTpVUFZ12cS2rFrgFL55fHwZimUr5oRlvFq3xjGY5u9usN5huWW0P4tUOmrb1l0eZiZaRjnU8ZoWOY0SQyuzPQrUV1sZsTUJEjkTAUZgOktJ13wqfanYYKMEUnKb80q21phMT5eINyjixuJZNmrEjU@e1t6MBkRJgad6WqjK6pYubBLvi169dAXTbc3qlLbKrtIFNNVZlxjhhg3uJFR4k1CNn0cobtcyOvGXX41MWQJkqXRdKCxjXyM6JDTLnuvmBNENuUSEe2gU4VwZSxTdzhBBA9OG5YuDAdSa/Y5WhlfV/gDEYlYX5sDwIH3HVg8bkHHuyLhxxPExhNkUQXWLoF0V4H8EOAYpdYkOnYwHBFTWWsEkovNhSA2it/FGCGSBqhW9gsQM1Yp8TVBjq@FRJfeoCU/g/gL1nsUgbsX0bxx@wwWFVI5V1ZYDhHevfrTW3eKWzvRvqUsaJHLqlGbxvDqZ4KGCu7zUtaJAWbgKilee@pkOavKVNHkNQj9PrVh4AE1gTQMx9aAyyr0mDt44hG4YRE5256ZhWGwfakf3H8n/rWmsYxWEA4yCUNfaAepndAU0D7BoCHSQlSZo6XFcAlKbszNLa0lVNVIXibQZTtYreEOW6qUOITMqtErHKr1BdZpYXsWlXlPtIVLFpdmUixCj6M2graOwi45w46WKPcsfLG6HGpQtN3JDs/igpCkyI67s7qysKGkbuaxzOsZSQz9DKG5HhhinIzlvkWNdEEL4kggvSwpME6P1TZb6HziBpEhn58pyRQTFa6qHpB6aWkr32chQfjl1KOuH6EOHIca580ZEE5KoBvslbU3hpxI0T887mJQcen8/XPqTRuK@rCr3dt/Gi7wWbzV4LbbXnkVcQ28Drj74N@ryOV86WJquP2rVPnz9gNdfclPAP8ygdF4hMSACIO3jxJO7xh@kdl01Ttp8bboRv2jHSchdrwfLMQhbOtBUBjsxoRgkZdFZB9gSwMBPWjC1kc7ViygEExObkrfMJHdqlykyzCzzV6MSEKX6coz7ARRH4UV0khO3rsZdxgWABQq/9wkVgOzaBptFaBBxxhP8KWcqH/QZprAvM5l7oFbbUq30QdpDnWAd62AaJPdSsdItOQ7YVyMEiQItK8@HcbWgjn@6SnYfvWz13npZcZV82quperZanIBu8eRnlvHb6mmpgxbKcUzLHZyo5MAnkwNIDAM0xAjj1JkvUsvecvv5at@f6ssfdWFY/cOrL6uG/N2sErOaKjHdpUpMmkByddHxRvlMehIPMG1HZCGvitrD9Y2z9cG80fWNl9bHN7GrNJ1kHlO1@HpJtcnVWHIYRpUKyf@4tCKUtTynzx2Z2@fKvTmhebzTZfjJn8vwP/YyXDO0QLTRO1Yaa@j/HPt/hLFH/Mrhdn273v7V9n3NO8dmLCe336qU81A19j7aOp0f1k/nO@sv/1pMinvN2jdT@JsU/1rc3C7yIzzAryf619viXnEXk21eFxc13/fhUUrZP4JS9j4zZWKqxS78s7ehy91cFPcqPmX/sbi3CQ@NZhNacjp/vnM6367j/07rj6R@2LsrRvm4rdQJYdrIgsB7gRIiT2b5OE6LfGatDsfIAtoczzpIceWHQivUYAyemTe366KrAAMx@MPbUO7f0rAZoj8SfkxCiCZ84kLDPkisHmeCGWCq8OAPVUGrvaheKeCExppALSFttDp/XN3EretzwaAwDTB4E6Rmcig3mBcuVYzwZvh3r/6RY/AonjoZEIzs3qasituyKv5vUU0WycV41FyCal9Uz2C4klB9H3Nb4lE0mYQJa/yDcBROCcoEuoOKDl6z18VLCYfRDxz@91QXrrpUUPv7uM1nc7ig6mShnEcfw8yKLskqegezUj/j/tjmuv4FghsvbMNzMvp0zSBKLmYdupDg9XRxnLwkJIoagponjEpRA12uU7sMMHCAYPxjYDFIAeJgOhvV6GI3UNjwrAxi718GP0DT8DJZ6FqvDcnQ2f@DSze3xuGEjrjM@32HrkkKh71X4SSYBoxYh1Hzs2AQHiMSDwxGfOGg8VRUX9DhmsSGJjbGElEc9HC5D6vC6GEk@@OSPv5JpFUKjxvTdT0OnlMXIUSy26nSqQnI5fDRAroivD8eJ2l6PjVuMtDPbA7CY4NB4qMhuDmY9gikOfZ/TTdiTSl5Qe1If0ql6QuqiFozVRFeo4G9CkezS@Idc63tSePpmWDW@Q3renGKeN1@KlfKOw4SFIdJnM2Nbfwy49hL2pcsCHSA6Qco1twSSMgDMqPdwkuwFOJ43PmegJZQKsGERP6r6m8y7SmMHh7R2T0KBwHJiqsOgvHA214UUwLMWRu8A92dSVTOsGpnNoirPBfoYEUUx7NwY2t7nRpEK75O2ht3M0mbNSh5GkwXNWrcRXI5NL3YSS7UMHwbDiV6hZpNcL48KYnP8EazYDaksJZNj1gHSJnpKVDB3Snzu8PnR5/vv35@WAY1ZQOTx3QsyaR1LeLy5zX63h8iUgOzEWbh6VvtbK4zk7txufQxeuS46R/bZF@zG6wLiOMqrgHRxC35lE3iLLhgNUGzfTQom@1wghrSqNE43bApM7pqwtHE1TO/WMQjXTHWVUQWzAAbQB7smD65PR2C4LmR6FZZARQQ6dZOgCOHKD@Rc53dh5WKmVNP6akCgrVS2WMni/NsGIHhWfpyNspI2xLNnUCVQMjh9j@LtoclkgtVp6UufLTjW12/3jLn9t66M@@9uZK6j61wmXCvxwcLPX7uTE6mOUAQj6Kc9ZHJ//nvkte6TkF0hm7i4dUL6p2vkaOrLNSf8121binuwmAlkO1dNQnnyTNG@vSTlsnQGfcWVQLX6j0Dq7rnvrPrmLjee1ir19a6vv/Eew9VTieIADoBYRi@hhK9Fr7rZ96ZI2K109MRXkC9ikf3vn3x@acw5BgnFsbJyXdnq49q5VLJ81rYhcCn832HL1/8Bb38U69K3v6j6fhS6DINTCVVGO3L@KR@Rq0vO9i1Gs5CkJyDMJHexweL18HgC9CW3FIAJMCwJDoYB4MS7QZyvqyFsUmoc@HlLDaNfCc7uI73fuBTqotp2G@xr@I69t@6A6@VwJ8Lu4oNqMJvNqn0BDL5GNWUo3o0gtX609cvPvdLu4HCUv0ls6K01jHMAYxCDOPiq328jirDOiBViKsSPq1HDAP/rZWcvWxfdmvBXql1fX1rez5nPF1QfkopA/fcWVk4burfHNLWNOWCxST08QUvbZ88f@2UIS9CsODLES5vCxJafIjV13Uwu6GkoCVw8QrT@P76ygq9wyyz2Peb9bqHiCjXUFqM98dDsTyxpq3raeD3XEPIYBItuS2pWW3W@CBLXGtsNusbWx@Np7BE@Hgh/UoMIsRHq@VtlCxWQDcMfX3z0groybCa@g/XV7dfRgf//O3Oq81Dt9v5rOGUne9jCtufTuwGTIOrKqtFIGOngrVLjcCTi92gNgl@GNfWe/UuaJ6NrV64tRFu159sdzfCJzudnZ2dbn99u9Pb2Qq2NrqdGoK9U5bqZTQCLclh9sdq@/er9jbFbLtZ3@n3G43Nrd7GTn@nWX/yZL2zvdGrr6/3txvBkyebveZ2Z6fzYa0tbU8BBKyWu7h25CXw49uVu8IN2S65vf8D)

In this answer I used a [suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/189706#comment454219_189706) from Sriotchilism O'Zaic to make polyglot close to 2:1 (width:height) proportions. I didn't want to touch the longest line, so instead
I added 332 empty lines in the middle of polyglot.

Klein 000/010 follow the path of Haystack, then fall out of the left edge of line 580. After that Klein 000 starts executing line 580 at the other side (char 1157, moving left)
and Klein 010 executes line 578 (char 1157, moving left).

Klein 010 code: `@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<`.
Klein 000 code: `@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<`.

The Klein 000 code at the end of line 580 creates problems for a bunch of brainfuck derivatives, which I solved by opening another bf loop which starts at third to last `[`
on line 10 and ends at last `]` on line 580. Paintfuck is fixed by readding commands that are now hidden inside the loop: `ne`. `n` is from `print("65")`, `e` is from `echo 21`.
There are also 3 `n`s in `print`s which are compensated with 3 `s`s. Also to fix Paintfuck we need even number of `*`s.

Gammaplex code was changed to `ERi521@<`, it shares `@` with Klein 000 now. Could not place Gammaplex on line 581 because it requires the code to be sufficiently
far from end of file. Gammaplex abstraction test was changed accordingly.

Double space on line 578 is for Pip. `!...;` is Simula comment.

**ETA:** `anhet` → `anet`. ETA considers number without digits to be `0`.

**CLIPS:** `(printout t 164)\n(exit)` → `(print 164(exit))`.
*Note:*  Single line version is actually 1 byte bigger than `(print 164)\n(exit)` taking Prelude into account, I kept it because I like how it looks.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Shouldn't it be "inside the loop" as it refers to the bf loop in the previous sentence? Or both variants are OK?

Comment: Oh sure, I had to guess so I guessed *"a"* I wasn't sure exactly what was meant without the article.  *"the"* would be correct here for your intended meaning.

Answer (score 5):

## 277. [Brainlove](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainlove), 13075 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q8=P,k]PPX~~xy_)\(^'#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                          ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)[-'][(7     m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S  iii/ \ps;ddpsdoh#####]#######@@(~~####[##??###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退   @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet       /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\      #-----########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn       # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM       #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_             #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._           #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._'4o'6o@]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeeee;eecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 #ata",:"[ x];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1PLers 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrs94 Cr u Uithw;rebodyhar#8doc""2:2FAC/'='d  t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*         <e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsNn8uM17u5sckn37zoBodKFQIKoJVKGrCiTQbHbMjDdmNZbCK49nFaPRWnckr7zS2hHWOmxLDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIke0aK2IctElX5eTLz5MmTJ79ONg2/84tfJPBhh253dNZ1AxZYfsBann1heRp7PGKPDNsv5JclCUNteWeDnuUEfklKMJ0xx7pk@45pt8CNBe655djvLA/88oz1PffMM3os6BgBWGyIxXas7vve@4CZbq9nOC0fQi4zdmiAZ3tgnjOj6QeeYQa264DXCmMvnK7Ra7YMBiEsr@9ZAYEvMABhnlOcSZ9Vxp65nm9h8qbl@y46rjG2YfX6wagKliKEMDzbfbr1/POpyOuMfW5AzvpdaziVFz3HXtqW15qKoevsq5O9vWnXPPtSdR22dzN/@jJ74flG15iGv8K2BoG7H0y7F9jWmeUYLK@ta/lpz1X22DNuRFljnmW02nbX0mzHZCrrWN2@5TF0YW3XgyoLrG4xV8w1tsYxNRPjFseeU2Ar4cMM78wHT/fCAqMFNdG3rRZre26PGY5/CSnp67lxeAS7PkkOJmQQCI298SF2y2K@Y/f7VsA9obiWR96QMuvazrnEqe/Qc1sD03bOIJwFeO0PAiqTL5kQrcr6goY1NLAEYYEHgywcuz0rXhc@EC/k2u9bpt22TY4caxhYjg/l9TVmQ91d2t0ua1ldiDCGbmaY77KBH3Nqdo2OZmoSIhdTYb3zLrOZ2e8z7gXFgCzt5YrM6rlvbPYO/Lsdnw37PebbPfAOTLfdtiz2zup3IDrrtZg5MqWWKzF4zP5U6SLbogVhHAtKuH34bcBdgCh12pC9FmvGwkFeKN9UasNxAYUec4wepwizPyIMAJgoRtt1NXRvuZbvJAN26XrnrGmZBhYdE/Ots7Yx6EKKdhurBGjB9lnPhS9UpMMgWxA5QHwgbExMmlkQTCasYqsPjROr2EWSgfoOa/rSM4BGPF/UZWD3gELsIOkzy/Bt5FoQxbecFlFHP@JnLpQ2XvHswobGB6gYeATbtzwif4LLsBQA0ojoVbn07ACoAkuxxQ4tw2MnnmWlOK1avmn0kVLjSUJiLqYQYEE0Is6NjeTuwV4SiJTH0Iw@EKW3fPKtLySDaRW22CjDryLLZWn3@Q67WjxFM@ebQMh9TzFSrPKB@dnTUwt@Q72ZPfOuJYAqAVa6LOv2g6yh9iGDagAZzBpoRJN6kdf63VjCbGOqDmJNh4dqQW0AI2BfZahk5sDzkMOPkWqcQ6G7rnMG@ITCegOHV/lqDqoA6K/lZ5h1YSEN8DpyLwnDJx2gEPiHoDHuwjsdQih0O9AcBUbDdH23O6BwENMPsE0CViAqQtxvs69Y27C7GAX8ERTPtWf5QJwYZ@C0sOZ7tmO1NBZmgziPB@3xApIzACg5QGvoxfgLZQoCQ0W4VFT0@vibv9M6OwM4W6bpei1Brl8BsZvUPRqUWejgGBKs6xhdyhaEy2DqPDokcGF07RZxOsMZiSQoE5TqpTvothg11EsbmlzHAIZrAZMwA4sTuTsIII8Z1jPOOVe0OeVCwXtGEyqWEqC0qdgqe7QNtWRCMyeaUXuDoF1kan@XJf3sK2WzpGwunFqQuZSWWlrMZs/KQHDaEjmBLXkb5Xy1NdFdfMXOgFAGfSxfKwNEwBz3UhCOri4jmRDnAXTZ3mR7tYaWOQgsrF1g@U0qSc8YUeQYeykQDGA9J/sHWEVQj17XNVqijl8infiXwFg7rGkAMw@QaSOe4jnF@JC3DvIWx4dOzHo7gCwBTwIcjYKO6@SZajLZrLgQQElOFD@ZSXrNZErDjkZJle2KqbVtp6UkN6AZVQFnyVTZrJg1u1QvT0WP5wHAXCIY5DSWYqZkbH0ntot8qNvvoBABQR2/D0zUw5KaBpCDjz1VAHJahjWJUKl7A1ZBTO7SSgKemoYfEQa1Md6GML6KnE9AGLeJyaZptWItE1o1IDjwb7DXrotdPuUJKxR4gYOJGmcg1kFkXpAtXhCeErlMFukcqMNBaE2LFdWmDVSN7QeYtCDiWNkg@HKehwFonOpjNYqkAt0U7@/HLQBr2mA9aO/eiJkWMhHgJhbvITCRATUoH4RZ5rZZTs0XCpON5kabCbzslvod4Lrvsrc2DSx8vHUg52BtkJ27hnM2MM6gSbgORDFM0@oHgvNASfwAeMt0B0KOqugNNb8jLT6aTpt6hVDmGadB7YdqT/RtBrILIYurIGihPMcFfNaCRmlSM5hMHQJcTCUuv8YgExl4Lc/JQtilA5HxVg6NGwj4smNDK72k3Dmc0fFeZTp5cIqnDqxabUdJY2b06sO8pGUjJ8zGXBAq1uhNONBbIqjqhANVftzhdsiG35sB2I2yCJw95qplDQ1o7w6YPddxZwAFREZgMcikD68HEK2OUdKFniiUo6ixRuJvVEVQZ8A1oOUD/XWCoO@XgPHbQWfQ1IBSsifeaD84cJBYsoE3sgOXm5tdt5ntGT60z2yYQtYcNO3hVIHILarDN750ARJV22cVhqwXqE5Jtn3gm@S@jYFjXjJJOQSCv2UISIE0QJTS9okV7wFTOR45piJPEKWcYTK2XTkFBowYoeYLlMYms/kGnKZzicHimdGyGCrreyYZ1JiQieAxOGVLejBRtHvmUXogy/BqG13fgq8z6HbROnA4l1N4559iV9KDB8DaFErO7vW7tmkHDe7LHj4UQgJbgIEbykFtFIJSEOeBGCFrwFAgjOh9eGgtcI9JelVSUJAH1xMJW57nejzdoONBp04OGEyKI/W5fT5oTWHVQTdEp4xjCBSQzQAkXhhfcblniggmMTXd97IkYgpJBeNzpllhsoBHSd0gHXLFGpNFNCEkVkTWYlWoYI4yHC4EnoktHlu4xQu/7fawa2MvSXzE8QAM1G0HJywkLlaQVGHMlCoigYKk/2RSe@PajnKVXFhYSJaSVRAXFhY2wbSBpk00pcG0SSaVTBhOQxPFyJAJfWsUA93qyetaCHmYqiMvGOIQ553dV4xaqbRczxg1XXzz@E0BkUF3CaFV/ACcZKpSQWMqJVcvoaBasz1Z@m3s8o9Nz@4LJHxhXBjcLrCwTGgAqnU9rIsy4vx2nPQqnqX5MLQxO4qXPK3lTuunV6et9Ol1MoOxU2Wj0oRCQXpKTzvz3EFfyaVqKyVVr6dStWUQxZqVZC65pChFFQalMK5KfVZMpQ2ObSVpgSignJ4mAakCPzWz4xG8YSafSkWognygtAcjByWpXRUh/WaqnkonIW4qmYGBaCWZBMyYiASfCo2UP4Ggg6MvOWK202mJCBTG2Pi7IUuAGw7hJ6MfDt69Q8bNYTQjCusODD4e7IsA2X0nDKuh59QQPPRqthl2IhNpfO62@RhvG1@7T/cka0i19fnB3u5RhZLpGP45CFTqGYbN@gGIE4bX0qAddQctS5oVBngmmMxxTnA2BBM/M02muoyCqSbPRKyvNNkcaMBocUpAc5na7U0Wwe9AfrcnykBAyJ1i3ia8mWGWePCZeYqS3IPuavv46cSkX@8chClm@l2c/FA9XgCwZpe4Y4s@CWCHhu/arRLbpxGnA9I10BYI161oZsNxHRU7gnBw6sYT4tM7EILcUNREMcqeCIOA2/YQBvgJnB1C2Q8HYEBCwMAAYQ4MtS3tJTE3mQGTxPk3GInNGgodcilSM/1x64TRDhj7XcMEFj4J7lRmpwAQOFA2O9snVb4BGEZGEwMjmpW4q4wgR5qGg/hr2TTqHth@B9ELAynsAr02YBWH3DiWJKztMxNE/DPAtDW0RV8ELfwYozwxfCWFY9EtPshCKsMBAmYqnIsk6d01zYFnwUABffnkD9t1LmzPdRDJ2i6ABlZUxjqYAj4LvUBGW1v7@Z35@J0FHDB2w1mP4TYOdRq5pg@ty3G77pnLliAAkqamccLed3DOFjrtwOhDi7LfEYK2zlxnNEWDlhXNAq8uI8nzmSkMmaXw2hvoBdjsQo8DzCnz8f53dqG31gu5HOQ/tOXoiQoZgzJdRnQ02TiAWNfoIt1gTX7H6ndG3gQ5@a6YBQpoKpQaJp@XM0B@hlyJFv6OosYbOXeBdh56tULTrLLv0oAIpyL7ozmlnxA@eLOBEiamnNE1RMUE0BsVPq5fZFyn2Qm@FVbdhdruuYGR/UoDFo0vCYcHqs1kP5tcSGZVFd8yebF8lWVb1kUWudQY8nAXZ2pmwB5alplFX@zcWGiYiZ7Qcw5qTuFx6AXF5N8QB1HM6fKfpdPI2Cl3Udo809DJn3QGlmSZHZfJpzC@ipdMhg6iY7csFTAP0i8OyqJoYo1LCtwBjGlbVtfu2cE@rUJ0HRy4acS8NeRawncb@M0YwKFtwWiEz7aMOxlcKRj3Uc4ZD38EnJyg@gHTOEo9q5VdGkN75rpeB6e2dJpQyUeo7wmPrOv3W1owBAA81i71737Yzz8/2NltHG6dPKlkB76X7dpN4BEtq9GDkXwXmsOcB/OG8527QDu24/ZsKFEI8t1598h1Ay484FLI/Z4ERgxhPN1pPN1/fLR19G2ROerR7d6ga2AeS4tTASIYxxTmVjCm23RBtnAGcyGBcHHw@OBpCOWLF0/3txo7u4cHJzEwbwZd29CH2f752bwCfYFBmK7lOOoPuq3JNSoao09MoQhmgwPOMoOBOVNVeKvoxhPFIamGHigiY/eoqjinbeCsvcfyem59vdU0ikVrtWWurKy1jXartZLXi4V2sZAv5OC1trpusfcUXFWtIU1bgYlPCeHsGaYBmaePrq2EEg6Mw02QWEYz8xX53pI5s1Cw1lbWjXVzfX3dyK@1lo18cc2yVtfaK7mctarn2s2iXly@NXOxbKBoNbb1aPoLWh3OlJAnMD8FPhPNgWceZL1L1srn86tmob2@nG8Vciut5nquUGw19TWjuW7l2ivLel5vmXm9FMYFHguMIduBCkOp0gHRNPRSdfBMSWFnGq9iWjcNF9YFw1lcRhbTDxfGceAgPFbQYyCWxQFm6F5A93BRHOenhPsquvdwSXwsyZI1chQBixQQV8Y1rxk6rqNjtCY@sVoMrFLwz1n@8yMJyFd67hqBX@Kqeqx8V7pO7hdBuz3hnCfncxW7su7YeZmc@Zr65Gq2KOwNr5mBI3grBI@vxc@Ed8NrZuAIXoHDwzX82eCmfGYFjYCtEjBc858Ja8pjRsAI0hpBiu8TGPsVyW/eJgGR1kzvuZEi2OsEm6//N974DRS1G2L5H6mZN5ATkMSeuiA/P7Vx0aI90WKkaAR@KsnhNMLkLBr6cNklezE1slMv5Hg83vZt59ylcXJkauQ0vYDtOYrdO@/ejNmGkQW9JoJGeQjlmDm583vNNr1mBMA@dnoWkjxoilf09NCzGtkj@uBk76wcTE5bTyTftNoDGPRkm7aD5juCqetFCtluNu15QQETuHsi/M4IVmJHAxh45rUVTQ9HubhMBCyazzmf7B9QwKZBY7bJtQ42gfxg4AUQS3z/63dbUAk3q6hjjGjoFxkajnWJ1aW259aYiIoWes2u3XEnT4gh010gTQPXi41uZJgNmmpfVTuG18MRlqhuIFB8ASXcQms853zqJfzOTqTECMmTayrMsXvMvLGXJnBd5sOweVw3UytBPF0aXuMiLGGED4JtiyJ5WO@8RqwhHw7GRB3oc2bkcDp/4YING295CDqDYMDfuMvhrhq1@/i7rbWKkLmC0dQtEI6Npm3dUv@ecT5ouSrIeFRkzNjqjLDj0tM0ndruGufc2EDj7OLzAnr22RlIEuI7L9hlB0Y1NBzNXtLnLhLxnYHfV5tQWQG0IbJRq@jdkoLX5e95QWyxFzAyzMea3aXXPSo9Ii4iFxDmCNG4PUuNIc2eQnPXaI5wkN75dCrDBEm0AfZTMdPp3DJ2eNGSd3xL1fz42EtS/PX12bH5xjCOklkDqyzfEKbyqWMqs9gidkfFQh9m94yumm/FjHOZezhpPDbNCEozNqrZNXwgrUBUh3UB1Uev28gdOykTBlze2HQLsY@zE@58mLeILjiYaNWm27V9bNrdecx0et1xnCZuzaNXbDLanoXYFklLfkeNTLP5gmsGuII9h9DuweX44jEuz8coR3PnIc10L/E3V8rouBcWf8/u897NzNU9OJbaJZKwzZmdS@tmLwJOvIuneVYfhH8gJppt1Wmoy3drhNsTCqv9tzdrAfdC0Ws28s9nFiYwuzPdJxtOOCMSH8/dszH4dtf12TG9b8MlFMz3@Xt2M4ij3TYclZaP4ubZ0USm@kwTk7JziMHonrnd1eJZ1oDXXIoZeG3sSMT3viwzYnm6fjfLC@Ur19HFd25fcZ71zu@qO1rJ8HCDQ8x4S7c9i@@JNcz5BQQSxV1Lswu3lytSTC3Lh9fzKsAzO5fGKPz@Et3RPOyG3VF/RPI6iI8YYb0IhsDjMvwvk9rK7am17sfTboBdu6sQsco971rQ@9H7RpWyfE7/xBh6Lnd/DtfuDqyBNZPBHTTfWLjB/5ZRzP0zlRPFWBSToziBhFOjUah3Yvx5r1xjx4@2WxkMMFto5HeKRzP5XR8E@z6O0A/BcIiGmxHPnEF/onInRoHO0e2Y6/TDlu22JjKJPp/KkYp3C2ET0r9v0e/WwRkfTOJSWGUll8sJoSg23T1huW3QthzFfWPz90TC5DJOeRwWe04vZpydxnjmFarePvdVnAO9H3fKz5tRoMDr61nHdqxghO97Mtqm63Y/pfaA37ZslPdAisUlortq8YYsJTbNsfG0iY@TLs32vAkT3heJ0SwgDsfstxFCfJL2XjWsonADDfRsynr7FFJsyveuVKCHp3kpvsmiO19QFZMxulbU1m5tjFz8dZtW1@Cf4erKbfDWteVb4UXSipCraRUMV874Wtl47TUxxbL6I0CW3YJBUcfqWWS9ZTRhtN4M/PAzN9DQxd8Mb41WJufF69vAIxx8T6zLxaSowHVgGBcY3pmF46Aurp8L13l8OZx/n4nc/Z5xZvEzZbcxzvHUCO6w5qPHsXH2JEmJ708zIRrfJHI7KUBjOrdGfvidCfDZyIT6HPTunuWbavcmbWm6q6Fr2ZnLDneIiU7H7Tgdq8P3DEW2ec0DKDLgpwFvKwTk/6xjMuJP8f1Mccx23W73PphF/si5peu2Z@ZpF8@otSDqJ8EdGU3wEJ87Zw@hmycEUX8/r910rAH0Vr4buH1LJdu8oF2cXOLveVw0XAb6ZWetbp1RAIyE318WvnlXxDPDDfp9@jT63YFPL4qq0tHCW4ZsfOqckiS6ZK53pr1ze01NOGp7/PsMKnwOs2niORfcwsQp2zpzm2bHvivTTcsIHPs8G84xceutw95@DE82U3fQWevagF5vpCG9VOL@x/jZn1fpYrqKd2yRYTYVlNj2wPNGSOnhXDRNGdCWrPGZ5TFXmdyfEU0W8@UONMzLlVh5nOFNMgTu3At3qN2y5iIWKueSJUntKKGrVg7EHH3uvNXE9tFYm1pe5q950tRU@SlTsfXhT5l4FdsqaArSjs0Pg/sETU0sds/s4pzO4My/yST5skALBDN8zaz9rTM8BX6PyucVDX2Z4YjPvDrId7O4Xx6@DajNgXXrEk/h1jUeCqd3VcO14dOAD9TrYO6EXdfu@/zN1HZ@puhxc9n6ZqjR7LG3qLOW1earMGi6S2bsuR6e2gLhRDU9yzdxEh95O5fEOB9z3DPg8WqXjQOHYWcW4eZK@UySiPpO9evn1pmBWzqf2ri7szuDUgDq9IL5XUC/NTB8@1sDN7BmwpteNL8L3DPjzDafTGA@BBZiVOz745@JpoBON5F/2bF9OjATGm6ZuEIi42SLdNaAkcOsId/UQkF0vPz2uZmYyCX2mzN1n4X70iMDLlWgvzEzrVlrAG6fBp8jMt02/W8HNL0rvjOpavbGg9uSvxz0@gNffGanTnuD4pPjvXNy9y9tYJXqW@DQrGN0g9kT6LHpXZDeRGc6Ns6T579jd90z9p1ijoGwB8IbivczCO4xdOuHRgAtwplBwJT2HF4@vUSLMycq55L@W6AJa5mptmMHt88SBYEBo63wi4XhHRAe@8w@xbf26FMhqCezMfL0VkkWZICR2UW1Anzfnc@angVdKFdmEG2Ru70zM4EWj@nwPxoj/QNx6heJWdvhaoXodxzrMj7@u3XRqYSdresMAhXPF9y6nD7uZFZv7WRKbFhcjdEKU761@@xFKk4ytAf3LhHXgjHmwO@Oxqa52yGmKNF2QMqbz5wnQ4cDlR2LtEQc0W7RO@Js9fH8GvUBO@6swdThyLOCe4/GoEcZ9HYsExdB70z7ufsM5Dvo2/rAhXtHFj@eNsFcZkfEaE9d0@gCflp3JnNMYGd0HuNxu9G3mlC/3bFptsA2C/COERhzBCyajqTBZWS6k1bsbtPy3tA8Y8w8b7w8maEn1pAGLvMJhjdINTBNLpXjjN9Ec5leMfL7ruvwN3HlHHz0Z7dzH@gv6HX/xX8NN1FPdIczx3@TpT2I1A/wo5PziutZTbfL31iEOT2hY/N9DoZnW372qe0MhuTGVBDmZo@P@F7inLZGCmCgGYULrNEmY9wzJzjn1CAMpOQLw6f9B7OHPhMbmu@/26ljeKaLa3LC8IkrcrGTaXcw9WjHNt8n0YRqGQJLM8yBOON0V1a7vWaPXnOHLrG6PrKaePKvSSdTA2M4S66cPMEmHKfOkIVMDZv@KlMOYXCUunu@bHpkN4lxu08vYumXMwklTO65bZnvjNS9RlWx9kQT1lmDBsAzm9TkJj2QgLqWGnRwy2c2uG0mPTwdPGM5ZtCzcAV8ch1oLim5fofowJ295h8xWs8S@8ZxzyI0@dCM3FbdmkuoCB7@Dx5/kYUOubG6groTBkP1DNjY3bsMIPMDzxGf@xDboesHbXt40EetWK43j69gsQoQBT68EaBpaV4hoPacQZdPhpzFNpX1WjTQA7Gw7YKpS6w7sFTLuVBJW9TwZolcjxTeZLdQ3VpgtVQxPYKLGurTUCqLgonvjJXcmftb9Ts2uF760ZIkeKh9n77Zvn@4//TgROv7@i0zmLhRcWB3cYGRWlvoBlgh09x5sDeGF1uE5fvu8LRh9vGxrm4/3dcwwJx0@UKKCh9cJJz4zN@20e8YTSswssbcwRP6WsFswfHJybOn6fHpa6Zsdzy3Z6Xi3tvHxxngPOyL45ne8dh70FLa7nBu9P1dXU/NIOUXDi1UzmOaM1KaB@nEgiEwEOYTfhD4TqHLdPtW62TUt76CHhUZt3/P5FfnFvK5cWGfYYtk63MRRY2WrWurK6nYpnQY4Vte9J1Xn@d2HzmnSZ8s/8zdI4PixHLWW54tUty2DWFatGE5sT3i0yLpuZvUGtgqtIyzDpqyhv@rZkzX9Xl4PjbaUK@sMLeyJgPMEji67qw9e@KYHek3ixTn@BlxABTcbE9o2PC1UFmfOC1LUkc4KAVHwzQHOI8KFKMxCqgoRjqdSkki1hPof3uoCQwj@XToG2igzHKhEeWCDjBVCo86PxS2aLCNCssv51gqVebqc4CNAL8cWGXWtkPQwJrtMweyEOaAVJlhH89VWPgMhrJBCLdWY4tXw1KupF@jRo2SzOp1nmN8KJHdYZ/0kB3x6LVFo15ZTKpqcjF56pRYLhkFt7q@NTu4MREWMosfkeEIv1xHoUsKBiNslrnWJ5CmUEVax3Ba0DQEc4Hye1x3EVeMdYKnA/7yD1tCcxxpSOzZvtEFhKACSOBzHfdyk6cboqvfNzxSA0a6ibpcbZK6vSUUinGFcVBdL/ZOikJrldA2CZZDPtUe5YJTDu4SwEPoAScMnpvoQLFIOIoVFsp0u4OeA3J8K@j4Gju26Xz5wBufGBM6OJ3Aw6XAVobts5aFu69JbQCtfHdd9zyS7P7yD7muLlIeIA51h8mT0r1YiqgjQCcFWabpDiDXIZB3lueKIAoi2TCDAW4xIZ2P5J7CI/WkRAyoXQ1VaFEyXI/W9tYxU3dZEjXBoCKXst1WFreOPv@qlqtXPrBe1vqv382mrgTi5M/U9VVfzrAwSPkaCSvuXQDvsW@SyYtDmScYaVawxdTBJa8P1ITJiQyVK4Q05rr9sNngWJTU@EXUKLTpKGimeg43q/ZIsx0RrHVJurToCK@Dog6p5PShgYE1RaB5q6ssKgO@9UE9DlgBEkR9ZAbXbOeiJku7Z6FeKIyyOGTvGckkwBj1Qg5sHJFdVEXWqzwOj@ksx09LZXes5oDODVzktXyhQsVZbFQ2qmQCoddFHX@1V6fDfE49Ha7t1mF4LZB6ejr8LJf/GrDuehDrYRZb3u7znatFrZp7/943RkyWr5NlfroL2MTi1eH@4e7xydbJi2OoheuQte3xM54hr0EqomPbHbdL2hMBLzjO/QT@E9nGbBB19KZSUvyALQUVuJZVeZEbY6xpIvYd0WfF962Y/80Agqe1bSZFPQNQgUHEhljDwnMdiUzEFWrviMps7D@wAUWIwTN0M3gpoUpmFUCWCsi6J6rY/MJucrf7YOxOKLejbXNmEMRYlF4t8udFnImC67@XcvcN3//Vy82h3F5uCnNLuSFo5BrG2dvaf/riaHcyWtjJE9etrBfEyXLOnLGl8TFzqOePFLqIiLh1pCIzmSJwq@jMuPpgK7i0oFiCOZo9HpkolPIvS2PCBMxUUIt1XUghikI5QPkGBZHpg@8woI1lMeyjY@CueBEjJrAnR6DDjGuygJwgbcwaPmExEKpAV9j0DomJC36d9OPiTyZscVg07KMHPm9zc7qqqNfxGfzHeqXQlK@zIRPdmV5nKsvDr2s5Z1DgMGyqzPsotsgRIS/yvMtRflGDLuSp9cagNVYaZYoD49BLd42@HwqDCfbcDawSeztwSSlNyEwi@YKUNxtc6TVVLVfjTMpuYDAGQ9iw3yJ4@3vHFZTOuGhG/D1OcwMHOyoIxHVPC7URgYd62vl5fq4ElqPcFepJw66SJiV9oY4wkhJ8dmH7NozMqBLaKON0gVNiaUTBUYc5qSNiW10fZJIWdN8goQTY1YJwotEpY37UWHWYnACa1CKRMcNkCcP6lZvqKqErvcSh4mseeZHCEWQ/BjO5saCqgLkz2wkVlpdQgznNx5VY4A1wV3A1eSNKmIUSmdRO0OvGAs7QxHtqZT/@5u9w7bunAZh/KMzD3GOw/bqwtcH8G6GProPtn0W2PNh@xG2vslhlNzWUjvMZ6VuZey4biPORfKNgyBhC1e1UoKjKsbq/2j9kvonqerFCezDgH9cVsplwnMLsHlDGBVU0BucpjOtxDEepfQV0AsQFRIIyDoo1lJ7l1RVUVlnKZjHjuPSq0fZsa8h3RZHuyrcDVMIMklh2tbC6omchk@pFCJA0Sp3hEVMOMJUqAWOULux@5XXTZBsbG0z2TaNrVVbLnECyi8arZfl1lNFFCCvx0UKNQRyIMo4BflURTVk00noKo2JvltSTyNhaLqc3EAkVMkCQFDo7oQ4akDldgSogZscaBiQ2jcJREHBtx42pRw4BqQCIw@aKhSfb5PjYKC4OxFqpFq8G@SUGO8ZgJXkWxdZesdPg1KkLldEMqO9nM@jXAfM/maFHmlMW6ti6qe9YmdZWjKVhj44dF1dZ9iC3TMln88tZfTUVo1BZgIL8Ynt/DyChhQPHMC37jdv3t7Z39784ODy@ofqNQiangyVZsrqRPlW1TK0eGZJRvieR@ngve/zs8V6IyniuxpMOGGK8J346m7NSm87pnNRf8hO6N9MmjxsJ6bn7AqYNp@oeHSu5CX3sm40F3OYHBG@kqqSurmv1jeqpk7iR/PtZyskT2hISF5hOfVJNnpzOJmYxuozkBC8j8bVQ8YSOWifwUHLgno91WAiHmAcPHkIBDiBp2TDUPOYJGTjgM0BjZUt5fhuKT6yPzxKRhukoR7GQJ@G9Kdi0xrpBhVLMjuF3unZTgg68hVpyuUqrUGdTpAxL8/tdO1BSktCjCqIE6jAVt6cMS0ON9msoKWzmBCvDbtOzGcJLSdAIAF7ycOB32KHbj81t7Vih6QikEbYz4Gv3Fvti0INwbfocWTTNCfKJCpEBUckoq3xUDS1LqNkcplGVKaRXQ2WbouBar1VQhimtYw1b9hkwcCWVgZb@mQ5iVaQIBAtNqjedJPA4juHP8YxlHKWfpG11OAZu1AzNdlrWUEH1YaU6yKfonrx8eZFMyTdogFS@bodKIqd0v4YN0QhEixjrTZ1qbOvRlSlTOnTX11EFWw@3AlcYpHgceE/BCP2T0u4ZfaYMSCOzzzRGVuVUcTJ@4KWYWuV6jRyWTtOoGj7kAVIzBm2TiQiHKTgPqWQrUDvo6jst/Lyz@6yma1odzJRIii3ijNo2dOU4F5WSYJQEUUoEtoJ1y0qYI069Gqc8iIP@EmlJZKiWeIY36dKlGXwXcUGlZtWHMe1y4xbIsbq@XhK1Mclq1hmQxU0ur2UB7AwWEkqpgF@hqAKwhjdn4BUruEgIbOHRl5bjWIAgoJmeAX2wMQAi81KZ8LqkzPimBUohwbP4RGi@gIxO3sCwm7zq4g6SxWyZJmfK19Cnvj7FTrUtutVR9n/MatnylbLYrYyyIOikqspip6Knl5fS6UVnSVl0sKt/@BDndK4XQZJoaDBEGkIgdbGbKgM9g@RRWXTKi8aGstiq5JcoBlhhkHYFET74We1q0bjOLj6EnjoDLh5vvMqiT2pvc5qmX0P@sIUsZjNAM1eoJZTuSsLkF@10GvOgLTYwAx@yp8dp4tmnx1maPioLaTR71hPNbYqrRjVx46YojkDhLCoaGHseGbs4QNQIA6MioXD9eIbfHNmDJ/wlLj8wWsG0/Lj4L0/63J@xCH6XJI2EXMkw1zsMCBwqgES0ZoxUCpjJL36R0FeZrCxuri53L9LJQq4ML728xgrss8XT/EqCJR4ZRgBD9uzS1elO8eyCWe386ltVrdlt7W2xcpg5rx8efv3hw3DUSJ0qr5KJ7YP3sr4CMdbYOv3u@6yx/Jzn3iBYIrGUlRLZJf3hWjb7@vVrEHrxqVW1ahhEq3/4kKqpyXpNWSOHXnVtbSmzWlzKHD1KNiAbUOCUks@njhmzbTvLTvt@udXq@y23Q7eX1RP8efRI@fABDbVEYnOTu7HesM3QMNyyzs4Gu8aIu9uJAX72AhH32XdevnyJhpf0sHdHIn6CYjMmwpUaRiHB8rn8X/7pwnXm6rCx8Zff62WtBfwc4OeH18/QfKwXPltY@Ozx45WVDGCMmw@/c/jtra2tlZ1M4bBW2FxRcwsbf/HnCwv5/EY@u1D3fb2erJ1/LedzK7L2l7@fbBwefsv3sdLwWWY6GPFdhJ/OCgV2zt7Bc95m@E/md62Y2UBzs/0OO0gQlivEbJLJwnLy@FUSa@ddQtf1xIj@GglE/gLTq5tr/@3HB28TQaKaz7704Bsk3iZWiwluBAPYlkPbRaKa2MBgq9eJUbZSqYBx7b/9W4hf/QLgoM9oA17VQghrdZSoqhWK8j5RXQWDns9Duv/3d78LGXhUg0deWcvLm3V4lvDZkBLVIfhVq/t7LF/NLwni0YsP9YdkcoIOCB6nCb24cvCIrLb16CBfyG@g2bHwFigYpfInq@v5UyaqVBcVi4jQ8c0dWAfMUNPMTbAw6JgShAsQx8sEUQ2QDVEONwsHIibu8HI63MtTw1haS6/kHznll@KJDP9wzxFeube68Oj1Tja7UQUJAJ9S6dFpI8QNWyvKrvsIJwXL7KlwLeNr6KqqC8Hhdypat4qPQKDAEwsRFX1CxE24jW18/moc5lPD7eLzV//@r37yVz@mv5/Q7z9LiXDnl1q7qFfDB2hIrnry1amwOs/YM/44DvzDL7SiCzqAyYnmLRPRU63ii/6FjUz0nXITPtXIQiHGUeaGowRDpCakxIdslmE7YBdhcR4tlBaKpdVSPtsIC0gF4Xknw7NY@cYljErENuFZgD/6hyey4nuBXIQzBbn5LLDqfZ6Z/YMEvLpWr/PGXY3X0u3PkYaUpwlbY7LPuZASKjCydPoIqJUJIofnNH3H8wJ@mtYQtqwWh5uQEv8AT1ViiSt46mn1@rqmvUqXy@IfhMByZMOHmyB7yRU3ueo@ql@r6sarajpdo9zWqiLbG2q9yngh6K01Xm0A@PRGbaPibtNPI2JR66@qtY3JyCL@o0dpRPAjAFBdrDOWAhFTVRdmpJQW6IJ8VesKg4EK1N71xnX1urZxfb2xAf8b9L4WX3C93rjxT5/xMyfM2L@O9HJay1ZPs6IlV@tg17JVdNGyp2CowhfCQXciJa6Q1FitruLAqaLW9NVCXWXUqJaA6WVL@lJ@OVsYfra6mwfO4WPwvCxnl9DwHntfEJzWpQSORNb5gGSdHF5//Ob/xN/px2/@NVghb3iPKPk23@Lf03f49zbAvxMT/47e4h87eYd/RwH@PWvi36GPfydv8W@riX8nPfyTEhXGQCZc3Mx1cxc5/Vw/B4PNciCSd3IdvQWdFstZLDfKjViu5@otMFnwlwOTnWuz3BnLOTlH18ETDAHLBWhqw@cM/toAxYM/O5dD4LkLBql0sSskver0fd9gqVOpxpKvLRDjNF3Laat2o446mmrJejmRPT3NcumW5VfKpN/p@pqxRmP3@U6jkcXGc/rMPRj/Hxz04tZb/3sH7rMDt@fC/8HBwbNTYIPV9KO0@gieSjW9IT6biWp587SkIkmGDSCR3dg8rS6raF5NA03n0S39ic8YInyrC6cSjP5fvrwsU59dvrwoX5bJEFm5oSECiGDcALHKoq8HF4h3@jJLffMlPBcEl2xovATP0MQN2ZeXpyifwogk@gd0xK1/D//2/7f@n71gSq2egkZwdb2h0JPCv1Tq6vrqWryrKUURFmUD/tAB7Bjl6rqKRgp0Baaakqqnrq@5G7yV1AYHWMU0NqoUeRwQmEciSpPS5S/l7/eLafPnNAkCF4zVFbHQeHo6zOVS5Sa4RKsNxntas0qVaTfPYhPXGWF8qqcoRGGlXNaXuDm/ki@XV4RlrVguF4V5UVHWbz7V3Ka@ChLFykoqVS7nRFgYiZZDI4CwfMMsYyMvJ1KYWd7ylRzOd9INOkm5JD98qIgLpzb7/dTDh/p67v37yKnRaNleo4Huy@/fyw0ZN/5U1gtgzxXfvwemk0y5nvLc5UvOiqqzz/JVSmHd9aBUa@DN9Gx@nGbH8I0g8JR3dj8j49ZlX06R1vtczvVOkz//0fe@d5qs4FYQcl3REQCmwgobG6sr1erqCphXi1BweZHvLVLO0ut66noxK/PiMnkxmRBeenEtRa7XSfRniQ22WYWG6uPDrq4TVH9spZBSmiMrdQUuoZu@vs4d2cqqUkyvi7/KQopVl5j4g55rOb2ytLb0CAZCw5sPMtXylVFJZrPJ68qVUcJ5seuyKW5XwdOFxsOHy@uAzGKufCo1GjtbJ1sNvGYWV/2hQ2ToSBxawhXdvpes0SRmYb1ew4LVT5PJUvkRVbteLLBEsizCqUng9qy4TuVP@L5kt/GY8ZCgTv2WEn2mry1DTwsdrdSnDVhrOdbCNWyPue32AjhC3bEmbjfwrW43vJHm0vW6rUu7ZS1IicOnW9u7J5n8BvTb@b2t7Uz@@MXjhI7WwtiO3iyxjA5Hu1s7By8gxuHT3a3j3c/3v9p9cQjuvvTGe2dYlmENLKtxORhcvmVvbLthA/a6A9u2XdODXDQsy@pDsOgpW5Zp@8abN4bXp4dxbv3xZz/4@LP/6ePv/ejj7/3g4@/95Off/OQH8PtD@P2If3/0b9YL@P75N//sDz7@7u@B43@G33@C35/@/Jvf/i7/kf3P4PdfYm5/Jn6xcPwnAaxf//k3P/79n3/zGz@F378Qv5/e/P3mn87@/eT7838Y78d/cHuYH/1b@P0RhxWG/dHvcjf83gj/uzzcb/z042/9O/7/F@IPjb/38bf@DF/C8k9/@hf/5eP3/kM@X/yLf/XxBz/6@P0ff/z@9z5@/4cfv/@P8x9/@1/pufjrDz7@5I//@5/80X//k/@F/v@Q3n90n/@PP/2nf/1//fV//Os/Eb8/hd@/A9Of/vV/ANL92z/@Gf7/@I//9j/9DP//j3/5t3/8v/7tr//vZPgdbvh//sW/4e@/@d4P/ub7//xvvvfNnPcPbn1/cw/3b/4BXO6fz/vAuU@5PtXlm18qP78KNsapAA3QdTEsD0Lt45FFEyGfDUvSZyxRpakpnK0q5ovpJZBHl9bXY1NWEIRJ0E5/8k8@/vavAfn/FgAD2/8MNvjnFvD6IVnY119PeLI0Ta2o6a@/Rk8xBv06HuqH4PA@C9J57tF7CPE1efOHRcEg3f@NgkE4JoKF4SYzQGFwVyl3//k3//z3ySOKi86/NgEyFzrHQy9i8PdhUX@I7X5cmnjoHyLr@Piz7378/X/88We/8/Fnv459hbqyntnKQFd/@6wyBCzcIxwGXL1POAio47iSLbAFKQ@GhQ2cC5X09OvXkPsFMMEQbEkqLINN0qtk1tEMEdNgIyDDYRrf8C@trDO0gMuQXOHL0uD1OM0qlUpaGlbAj4KCFeMMWbUITkOcragAXIzE42QaRRjcsOFjggIxK@kj1liqDHnENDpUCQKSjYROR7Kel9PFyg4kWBnuMISFwNPSa/i@rlSLlWEVwX2gLACM9GNIEkJVMHfD6gewVwgmhJeGOx8gK8VKOl0tgksFC5mm1DINSlMvUOGo7GlG5UZ3xnB35@YjaDKyXpT5bAqgkonQ@E6PQ2NACA7@p@klURz6D430W8L4UE9Dwg934/6b6EzxRQCAq6q4KRB@qoq5eQTeQw4qTcnCJ80hAObSJFWFIMGBBJi0lKb6TZMF0oc8fNqzgawCwWFxFhcXwbRRlZflxgGMKWHw5p2X/MDwcNGSBMsSk1fXZXTGHVZ87@jiIQ0@l3aW4K3D/@4C7ZemspSXpMUkzmwkedbS7LM0/z16tMQ@g7LTd@wmMTW97K64CV7MjXRazkOSVRdsS1TENAHCmQf6T0uvEhJLUN1DY8nwN3y0CrnHmhI5vKpI6bE9QRONFEPTMlomI74afclBEwaNfMVXWyQJkg@DmL66Qqdm6I6@FEtR/ZgWCmJMeuafPXaHMALJyHJGX8VVrpSYyDkp5bGtSrulHLy/7ZZKlQ/6ypoEX7IP8LpAcXEdUE3H8ixtYwOhV69Umm5CI0iwq1K1Ktb5mS5Vj3dPIPjJAdPzOY3B6OVqZS2/Ulgp5JdXVwtreX1ldX1ltVBcBr66mivk8/r6ysp6cX3tepr7PAIOlSktNQsb1X904/kf/tGsZ7YrPlL1azbUcNJevZaq3QrfdrqIS//yaU4u0wwYYXSxlsvgX355Gd6Q3YxeWKsvLHSvVCz9Ke11vMLNFZBj6UrF3u8BPEx6ILEH4AQPpIGLn0xsV9k/KIutCXjzMd@eIOsFoGaojlMgZw5O@v@fv78nwa6urmI/KbHwne8ErFqFgZ26vyclgKl1WLixQbVbWkej64xbA88i3zPGdva/2j/eP3iu7ewfw0jr23imTJMS19fX7WjZjawWOzg4kLA3gRH0so7xr002GAzItwn266Eh9eNPecLWl/J5Nb@sLuuqvoz/dxjy@H//8Hn4z@MbYi3nJX6CuYvnsMLZyXXkm9IGV85Txcs7XaNViS64ZkrqqlVpuSadryq3K7W6hgebyy2t6bZGmh@MYHDdsv1@1xhVks2ua54nQ08bb/3C04eVrJHVGg3Ac@DCiJvG6Jv5tUJpIetlNdx7rrRZajO/ugYup07oBC4FdHk16bReamlhjp5BA4J4@VJ@tXC9IXT3VaE8mK8q5uJKZK7kuI51jfuNS0Yb0HBl8n06JTlfKMrlWnlsX1uVy/XrRz2rZRvsNIfH265mRlxdla/DcJA0DthxLoUpPbypBzeyl3KnudScyDmIDFmmnEobQiFQlXZe1IA71vG@0lp9I1QVVJU@fPgwpM1OpX0nELue8itFdGcSzhA8BEnroc6NhdWxMYfGE1Tr9BzqDni6w57i4YXAZScu3yT/2DLnhNjuGHR967bn@v6vEOax4Zxzrx2bq5OJvJ4YqKXe79lBZ06IF/0enkq3vH8wCLu9JmQQaYoHeAwvr@u6swKssReHc0r5LFIHhxukSB8cBD/a//zJSex7sru1/URaZY8Pnu9MfQoiUIE93d07iaxr3DeMWohAfHv36dNpq/iAuFCmqawFVljDDdKhRWcJIzDkTEmusWG9nADMBNcgVxfLLWewqT98qB8@xUMIq2wFJPHltVyptJhl0BTK11C0yuPzUh@3XPtWf8mv7g4PPX99BYrLBuwFVMBlGU9gt0ZAE4kiNFRZhua5t7WdTVaS0DiCRekZbsxe1/kpQ9uX6LAv3hCKtwEHEiqcabmXDh2gbHYHFhv02VxH@KATGj37rBOw4NINA0hNw2Dw@9QH4lvxJ7jdIeBpkNsNn@6M4LgPyG6znKQRF86vFwvF9eV8MVNcL64U9NVCIaPnM/pacW0dZJGcXtRXi4V1PVNcWV9eAbkJfAvra1ICZAi7nc2CaKrLMnxLANYx8ZarDbwuzNU6VSnB55jZO8VIQb1H9gGTLYgj4/WqfkBnT5bsipxfwYNhyzoDiAYzWWJvbzu3tyfLj9GCS2DbOVluoaVQzOXWHsuyRT7bINvlZdnlcYp4cl4OuCWXe7wtywMOANXVyXIHLburOG6WZRst21t7e5hOGy15jA/BzrkPt3RDyxoEc9CyvEwDb1l@G4GDcFs8oRXK6S5aME302eM@2@Any5@H@cnlAMIRD8chPAnLurUly/vcsrWFPttU8ALP6pdo2aJHlj2wABHK8hkYzrAzkOUmGJEUZdkEkzkywA1vFEONZQ60QHnEEYQokuUhhTbMcxmGh8Idk3ny5InRCVrWGX9GHv9Cw9oHH3s42N1rfv558@ys6Y22dj8/Qp/t7SdGezTwmmdNEa3ZgMeFOOBz3htNP5DH/UbD6M70@RJ8nCmfxqhhYd4axlvIk3jOMJFeYxt8tsFnxjz9kEODpwdBm/g87sH3sdEkn/AhH/oOm025jIQajPoWzqtjmzl3gBdkeobpuWW0DysLLKkkM6Paaq5eJnfWU1jqCngW@rcVuqQah1YgfV@NasNKrl4ZVtby4gCbIp8O8wVbziz0NvV1EE2MTT2/kh6W8FIDt51kSVXfVPSHS@@U5yCFLK@U5NPNTVWu6fXNvF4sra69WhrIcqqE783ltdI7GH8lYZCFr1Rtrb4J8s44ytpa2sjmS2u4yy9VvgaMBNAfNQeB1WgoyqVlnKdSmGPs5UEGo@KyERXVLreVYWZY4Rljo1R5WNHLXIcOy92A1ULlbQO8D5ZDPANww81cCdc2FFlfL8qQfjarpFLIlZCPwPf1y3DpNfrEDBNG/mispPLLpPXiakrD41ANt92gCzXZ63jI8cYF6SWeYCTtBeFGYxr6@yXpBAee2B2QYGU38RZ70v80lIZcRxPjc5H62rokVcWA65Df8FcW1s@fbGswBhM2VAan7aFg63raNvK8CR@uqCx0OoH@TXti4fZhM3Tb5noFtN0hjLNROg49QrU@mlDAop08KV@pDVwQ@dbJ@cnJ1@p1HOwxDD55RvD8VZm07aAmA1SdZ7eYUamCyUAxknIJKEhdEjoa1WqlUelZvX4wgjKH8b5kpFluDGjf54WJzoVR9Cs8Kyk8GpXc9Tj880GPPeaB6EBlGK1ReQz4zZUd1ERroXWRDRNDqdpCvXqPK4@vBiUURa/LVsXyPNeTE3gKddOpDBzfaFuHlocHIPcPFlmbWXjU0Oy8Pt3FkNsoU1@rVY85E/lQDLXaTE06xayIOuVbEUauaAs/LuFdw9BEeZUqvwWbt8iUlvY4tblSbimPWSMFLrnX7ddtlmerK2W6vEVBSMAOCHOIESNVqX4JgDnc81IJMiJI4hxgYkKLUCN2i3yMVN@@Lp9Vahj6Pb42VFmuq2rtfV2qlqUqcJfyKGFU/EGT38qca@r53Gp5CG762kq5w5qV5qth2av0YdzJyl2odjE3wc8lGLhHHZAEcN69Vz7@2ndTG2qhwt3KBOt9FwSJhtaoDMcVtFyp5VdWM/nVFZzJWF2Gn57JL@dx120mn1vP5HWQJ0DOgPjwWwP7CvwgDIgbeR3nO5SuIjMmZ3LDnKZndEvPKLnXdut1KnOugBxICEtlAnfXAaoBByQeIFmywtdIpfNLXaXlMmNDJfoFblemQhqZDuvbmQ6CObKMLg@eUtnyktJdVDDM4smgv1url0q7w/630EtR326uptdy6XepVFlZYKmKb70lDCNjJBT0F4CaxRwO8we9Wm4BCg3tT72Gmg4W9bV8qTZYrKk6lC73/mxDrsp1qKprJsFffH0Y5K0yuIU8kEtoYxlr7NZHsbprQbXq6/myCCL1BUdWZOVUDo/QKMnkWj6ZTCXLOH25AO6CoxP7TUJ3kHyob8og48kleT0P/mNGfiMHfNC@qkuJawmHtQyG74kr6frqeiO@o/BLNhoZaTW0PmTsLL0osSxt3NEaCbZAJlWr0iTzVmXr7GirLEJvbUuJEu19He9LZKdCBwJTswuful0ovVF9xb@nuFcOkpVIQ1ON1Wn137JJY@1XeCRskyWhXIbXq@Xzy/Vafg36cuDBYdB8HoruX0kc33x/WXYjXWXZU0mWifvwzQjFQoqXgn1IUHtn21fhnEaJbg5gilHi7btWT314bnevissqH3wrLPGBpbMa7alsZD8koH@8ploIN9F@@TpfgHpx3NABhtkBsHboTgsFOcXYAt@4nY82boe7GDbKOEv7mvWP11@tvSq@evbi4MXBHnuUKxVLxamJ0NNHmYye1JMbOJB7v@DivO0H54tvsTIrJ/rJ5ZXkjZWb00piWFkJt6AoerWq6ht5tgmkzUrQHbT1VTX3vsrptEoeq3nw@fhrP10ZbhTBngdxugSILqTz1aq@lE8l@h@/@dd4tPZq96utpyyJik7@7s9/P7/2d3/@L2m/Q/K6jG755bUEhESjvrqWuLrqX11dw8P9Col6gudpZS0FZr4XR09Us8JZX9NTCV9NiNnttULCfy80Hyn5XBH8tg@4TV4FFCd2j@xCXn@0gWjWb6AZEG356wkpUXz2@j1jYDGrrbMzO0@mbPYG4hZLH9QN@GcfcJL7g7rwulJdzOJk/TqGDqcPl6rV6hIupLFkNY3HyPOkYqJauy7XAen44ABvyaE/y1/CP7S/4g5Lvg/20NtaeuMvRVnYsFihClW8lM1mT1Mff@238/nVv/vz33zfeN/4Gtj3@vr6qp5P/AKyc8sRz3BwR5NDeFgTDdGgkM25mVYzZSmB1xW3GQ8fDhFxUIgKDrh6KLRJF64tdAA1AJcGSOQKBVvCg2oZks3pVHuqLEmRAEuyt3dmZggGW0Jl3NDupCvpAXpBz8cqwPGkB2NQ4NBDvVJmw@8OvD5JkgrF0@sZ9hCiQAoPUBPJAh2wE2xT1cssu3QzKs8yV0pEsgrrWb6PysiAq0sPIMpTIGa6Goz1DTykiSFtB9i0hkEon@TRqkHadUi7yyM0yFWh0vMAGcZzxyM5IJxLD/DEGQnv0KEzewMClFlKegAIgDIoArBdZxtsOcWu7HS6PNZddo2bGlFxhREeAZMwGkJr4bnHMHIZw9lcP8nAQ51dTNSwacUdQyAcBl9tq8CwAqOTDQUiOuV5b1AAi077K1Q09vDhOFeVit1KMSoRwkfVbahvbaxo6kYCACwck33WKskZ5qTTWNkPJskOMJ6m7ALVqWQYB2rjWTy0XksS/N@baJEip6qKPMpYAFFfvFWYgDKIjGjndWii8jk9v5ZiUeZNyLtJmSIdNtFA83T4mUaqpEyexWvpF4lQdS3wlpP4iEjQ7fQZQAad2gCViqKCA84MxOk@fgMS8qj9IIwdxYKi2F0K3bY9GFvQ8mGoDUdZ1lMYrR25UD5oM2N@heE@w0IKPxQLQ6POFAP1j4h0Fmj@mxS3@X3XIYUldPgbd2OSGjlf4upZeLYHzqVBqsd4KrR5MZYjrs8NKZ/UjTlcp5rP4@I6JVd5L3CTYdaZRpp58utM4ToCcZrSicClKBJlGEaUBuK42bV6kKVjy2KoNMMvZbNnIJAMmqQl45kNdNXZs6HrcPysuJMte2mf29kTVJypum0QcsWpzATKMHaksEqooiB9c1373OIDXWXiWK3P8qsZECIzgNnxDxBbwj4fj87mwDvDQ8FvDT5r3FjMxOIuKKPUze@yvqA0sEbfc9VPHt67dmE4MfzS814Sw1N/5Idn5ukQJ9i1iOVCy@QH55J4ci460SmJw/0VOniu4ax6XwFRLDzqiUYQXK0LCKHqEvYxwDTN8AwqtmIo7QPqAKjtQctCpTKBV8LD2RVUt6aY0PQEg3fYZ2w5L5HyPVJXILQLAAys@sokdPCDqFgOP2hBxWh8jgL4CrTOXgv8EqhjiZMfxg@pG82kYGlM3mxBgMNOh9KqMN4sQkshZsHWwdXlQdEXwHMVcjgjJwuKnAawaTklc9BR/OnonNol4iUldhNShiEEgWqAgqLCY8PnSrOFRpjLy0uNlBINPFuzfFSU7ON9ktn@mQ2SrJsNrF5fXHZj451n4j7HsUnl6tHx5tHNIV34uf5wxL@S1MZj0m8HtmcpybafxD7wAnX/nvVI4wPqYvCJbvZsUhduKrT26gsyy9czVyGZlZDM1GLyGoEwhmCGmVHGzACwTNM8z7QvW2Xhwa/KBuBQWVboiPoCvdDS80OT3W9HIdyA9kWH9mb33HS7LooeMp@HHSfNSxiGHIVWYe/bQ4jkWJdsy/OMkUL@KQyNdKqMSLphI@jdyQeM0JuwK65Wyx7WRvWJ6MMoOvRd0Vqsh/oepKvbgXJtZug/5P5D8B9y/@E40TDZ2rDOJS90usbiIHGj@qYwJIIZhWGuuTK2sQ9BBvGY6RwEhhxNuF3Dz6xQ7BDf3Ab1WAkJA2iCdCAqqHyxdlp3fOtyqZ7OngFNy4QIqHEAXasTTi9bkRmx373o9l1/wslB7UbQ@Yh8o5PZEdTAaQXLGFUQEQbHl41KcM56Gp@N4f2@KDBAQHELPFEC2AoUO1WO1M@SJxBOTR7jmGesJjJTJyFLeAk3kIo46jli44DqMUDoHhUJsgk@LGw5Qvm9YAIvPbx/OAyrkjJ70qObrCcBk1NNhbOUMlVSLFeqGmYT0I5SaWW6KKE/VEVtyitWzGtR//HsL3xy9tvQLmbnngiW9wtlKd5UrCHqDLVEcyGssmolVq@Qg@yS0bU86KB2uRgqOmVIZikbjiZ4OlgErutWiVW@meL1Q0dOZEcuRaQwqlSgiKMKb5a8XYQo5QiPovki2igkBBGfMxCAkZsZzRLRhvFow0qFMw42nBPtMpbJIWVyyKPw0MM5mayLaDBIirSpYvXUUYkeCFQywNN5b4kKY2XmGxeoFZi9QaU3MHgK0xzzHKICQUMoSSOdmfWZqddimY4xrSkASIg3ALT4bTslaZrh6Wpki3gUR2XIo7hNkAHnFUBgxILLXLGZEhEZDXVBrpfT1A9A25XTNUnWcR8Z/eX4T86EjuFPv@mYmwypTzrmMlN//yCOdcRsrIHGhAw9t4IMGQcsW6TnBcSSS5cpM4RncM@GNzVnm123me0ZuAEDb3OP7m9OheMB0uT4qO8GRuCurJT4IMgm@nohgrPYjRd8DGCfOS4MNeKKE22u6NFJoj5L0z1zbN/K4I3RXAS3aLMAv0VEisu9wuj6kiRmDPmwFEFzAkLRtdHAO8IaDcW3uu1UKdJKilYN6TCZlHA8C6ZYfOBDAuhBX3GbbywzSN0NE7WKimgntnmuHPSFZxIS2WLArEyQ58G3A6IK893xSJDU/aFo3AwUutKk4/bcMxDvUJUnxp4Cvz@GjRky@n3KS4YZOEQtxXSvUnNQzIyRElG//OSo7Mu8YqSi@PlJABPIyDBvGseIWW9Gco25yfFoYXrHn57f43h@j2/PL42qp/PMh9oV7vlpSS8rYwgQcJyN5buzkRGas29kZyIrkTMKUDzCvbPYog1OLczpFgTdEsG1NtBHJrL5pM9HZPyrefi/vQLD6Lv3rT4Dr0w8HgG/6eE@OoVuEfLDhUQFgu@nkPfcTC4i7Z17pgVh8eaKPZQVQF4lxuWgsihomH0YRvtytJAiAN9B87iL6Qbd09amCveckSfvIsPO8/OraKfRsrrGyGopImQmBjcs8RGMzIhf3a/gyOiI6bl8UKdAJ5WKa5pGpPNApTkkY2QuYnrGb4ThQeyIemjmm3K4Px9/6H@DNeOUXYXPPoPAn0wmSCU93SDQH/VHXMlml3T1hnyU9z@8JvHg7d0IATyIPRCZcbKp29jnkRIV6R49QhRWmywyqdMKuy23179Zh5@GortLCpUbi1QJa3lCDfi8Grdvq/EYVYQ0yZd97keSdxHdvWkuRmoc2JiFbX9aF3IDMu59ME0lDpG73FpjrnODJ6Abzbs5c3qVxgyGGsUkThfYNK4m@SIl4RB4H744gfQVfBHgmRU0OEGFZcM5KnErGyOfntGPSS3CBaRxgBLDYnjZA2UjFkoKzRD86jpK05ybpnkjTXMizagFTCYZCySZE0mKWsDqua0KulY7mMOd0QsHyfC5jW3D47iGh9MSV0k7WbIzLHmRLAFDTlrJ0q4CTDnZSpZ2yOAnS8dkOE@WvgTDuG0l3ydLYbPAAB5YyfAI3QULR7uZLG0rqWspwPs4wnS1ZCmqUwizya2EEUAFlhukRlwyc1xRzMCzoGMjoTLDkGL8DI6TaMIlQ78c/HPF@/yCGPDEOcslCszSTJ/oNGI9Bk8Huo1QJeuMllwSvfnuwR7tHRrfbAD@aRjMxeMQeBDDE8lJZsQzhr60QgFfyCDyzdLsHDF98vqLe2RHpA4USpU8mT5hTyN5oKWQfw0C11OTtyqI@GF9TYLgFXi/fGLkefm8kZ0wOcoRrrGmZmQLkfo6eUuhsK6nrgzhtR@vIZq7ngyEN4qGQXgtEdgYTwcZjhbbMLG@258kEvLFHYF2PA7NvvFGidQ7FY24gmiZc7zJWZQMGUO88aduK04sHmZtggWhZy1X560s6heIF6PXmNfFJFXe@CALMZ4DLdwyzy0k2x1hpHCc3WSor5jXDYVxeZLEuSbZJETWUIPIwAh46tHgdRf1inza8DWMOcRJFQUBxGJGqXD@6n6C/O5y@T0UqEMkTCUwS7Ce3ZXeFK9v7WWnct4dJ3uzAtEzw3ZSM4WjKIUxymF0EJPMb6O1GyI@buHgQj5PNII@Je2HaIvGBHfgbXpswWGhlOBdTDqe58HxPD8fUTclku6FFgotGqYk4PCCRzkdF@32vPKCz6pi9KGJbKP7yRXsTVZwvPIQHhXAm0I5b@V48hPXtsZtm/TdoguyVL3EOCOn5c@omseOwO5pKTZahgWHg8bRzsHzp9@GTndtbS0l@ujROH/YanFSNerHOWTatxz1BzOGLfkM6nvHxWu6Axfv5104deQbvIQzaxAG8J6bkPxEG08JXhbj51NtF@LxsDGMCljn42ZgTHAlFHUM7LJtgdcAEGIFypIhgITiLeA7Q6O1FM7JAnXglXmNBnVfjQZuRmo0RC@GVROucKd@kVjIDnyPbjvl2qgvJYkOa7OdA/byydYJO3myy/ZebH/Jvn3wgr3cen6Cx50PXzx@ur/N4Lf7/HiXjWcU8MEbOnBACXjdsUyr1wSWnc/lVhhB3nb7I853lO0Udz82euyJa1q4HrXhG71HHW7RHCuo8li7MBwd4RymTZfA9Owg4LfbmQCOhJsWHW3D7f8MwjZhTNvDMW/PbdltG8JKOPbt25Yfnr9iXRtqEPhteKoyw4UkvC2EtgLRTXF0yR/eEgfhcZEGwBj@@FZC2@cRrJbGBOKi55MxeLJ79OyYbT3fYdsHz3f2T/YPnh@zvYMjsB5@e//554DP/eOTo/3HL9CLAj472Nnf29/eIgeegZzG8EA7Xft3WxY0DE5YMc9xiZuuPI5s8VlnCAYSPLs06JCfz5IDB7mPbXTtd1YrWZbwHiF@sJDWBFh0ix@z3uJSZrjmS/sJ5Bc@3YSzmGMblBo0liq0t7JortDtoU5yXHjojRjeiGSV6YC5QubxTUu0KadlW0zexj0nOPfNz6FTWw5BQ0ILABtBhRtQKowU/CeTmQ0CWYXUzK6LOtR4anxToLBg1Efh1pGyRBgTe18QKJ4K2HdwPkgvRw5A9@CQF8kGHg/AliMHHoCtcAcURfdxLwgriBCD4GCA7Jmtcoc3vf4erf@ytcjhsUGj2KLIE683qlKDjS9Qt3v9Ll3RwGd56OYlwzdtm6L4FB6vOOh2w@sPmxaQPPBEcVkV7lWDkDIwmzYuNYhtbM6AGjb4AjXgvh@jHfhMqaQ0doKbfSzH5ndfnHUNh29pGm/FIdpjRVQ1UhF7uO3oUgk6Z9F3iQDxopfJfETxdoRUaN03HsR8fCNFQ@x5pIuJwi1ld2Xg8Y0M/DJgAJA6MdIxqaeik54Ixm0LUlZ8FygS520/xMMDObcGpjURIbyc8o397l1KIDkzMU4K9x1S7qCK8B7PDF@zbLsetHFiqz08tYJc0Oy4/cDmdahMlmB8tRiExo4NUntdqU6kRteJTqXouE4s0SZQ8ZxUm0CU90mVKJ4vkkfsK2zr0d1mtI8Os2M08Zrf8dpZBheRLi2cfgFBmN/LiL0N3bMr5E9pzDs@0F2ZxUp15/Gp@uF1Bm9m4GyB30YWbiLkd2v2MC1oHrTORxsQPZS7REsLr/fwB02MLfbUCW6JrTwEBuPAjg3jukeNcuTHtw/fdMcjKdPu5Pj@fYXHUpEzcY488DvKmLtlWC1MMkNx6kzs9YjxTsgs8HoldMkQzIhfP8LTJ1gLZcCIg3yEbsWdvFZDsJCwdM1BGziLuDhLVHcEP8WqtHUiFCTpUeL1kX2lPK6kq6nseOcIi6FTCVl0JoSM92qN959Qf3UD3M7t4IB/3x9c8dbc8e7hk6Dt3Artk/KmpufD4t1SDNb9wX64BSzv3H4psFD2zHzAvJO8CS2i9Ig4M4uJaHfs7Sm@vlF31PYADPa9OIMSAY2lNnBoiTpUdKrwCKk4mLFAdHyys3t0xGQ@PoG4wPdwyNASbBBhL/BbR/juWdshZqdFQlM0WI6Ep9BlYutadOzjlsY8E3lzWIWQQTICHxGzmLzjk7ie6FlIhKDd9MQQQ8xN5u4q5EF@TQC@Rs22wLwSYzEsKqA0s5gJ3vnYfnxTt8BbhsvG8T35tGOa9914W5c3igOKb/4xzvCkyOz6e8nl41KYDhewrLcDKnALJGm8sFZjx5BwHwJq2mQN3lItYZXipnkuYCdC3OEOr9ykhP2rExQREhfCuSwcY@tCOBZZ4/LxYijm0M5D7AYM3NIpPPkOZfAIWTy5bMQrNDXu9JTJLgiETLxH6lGcKiB6/bocXT2rjPvJSiSQx9vaIuWmFuayjrOzAnZ5fqDPcG/z6jR7mE4KuO2tSal/P0nxXmIipRDnMwsTegLk1UJh@S7Y06UIo6u/Kmzeh0zzz6DXh/H9GKQ/8ml6Hyh3/3km9B8TwC2o41vlwwYzFRFEnRl9ykTZqTOK5w/ywueFIDOoO9js4K1Zk6mm2HAqb7Oh8x4pDp2C3ChDrAlHBeWt5gb2r29PDhnynektfHp6vLFhINwjeP2L6HBdTOVKzAmPmE66WZ7nUDB@LKnn4vExOo1065k5OjTHN7TywqAnLbPFC9AWh4z4ttpMOMVAidCsooa37OGkXnl6Vk/Vy/ES7u0/3WVLpL6uPTEFKXtyKsZyFmzntgwQ66XpCOw16CjeZ34JfpCHTAgS0ESH8hTCTerOvBFGQFiu0aUMYtunYKn6dKW3fdNwUP9HRqYLqh9CRJp83T3YS82aUM@VJ@JD5vy@o0CsjKxqMkUFN5zHRUiTIHhtonusn5LwUgKxQfKWO3mNrF7Mra5LVDonE2R6tfV6ZsmsyAz6XMPp@QPvsnV@5nYu2qzL@m@aQ3P07i1jhRW2DGnlH3JtnfpqBU@4KgyVixTZeo4IVmRwkzSPnsqMaaRtEdeT2Xj4XV5gKTLQWLmEJyCmqJQt9UIqxJNyQaVXW61XnEqu3Ks59TKe1QvSlSCtpxV0eAidJ7AWviBfC@rYlf4iPttqORfMGzRHMEqKzn4wOvuB/TvOcIk92zRfTtuMpQe4WQ3PkGiOdalE940jZUoo/0gP6BCPjifFaboYZ1taNuQAsJ8BYdUf0nuUkh7ktEE/cMlHJKQiCbH39nvpQXjqKEcTBhCkZtfD7GwQnHEYBdd9uOuI74ZWdS6N6XjUMRUDUcOYxO3kU1nGI4CYUXH0qlaXfM0yzA5mAm@WfE/R2MYGv3L@Grxpkg53ahgeHXzI1dGI6xvw6dNiAiZBgrlPxzckKD7adTRwF5qCCui8C210l0gQRB/cxs2u6DgSxd8ABHDEP@AilSZmMIVgBXIiP@pHcweodG5yXI@rCHgKklfKAywswubpVcbAacc34QiTFWgC9weXiE6OK3hECVSdbDeKEYVP8eCEElqGFjYfcUlVSl5V/HTH0ZRYNDWMFgaOoeLBndjAiSwY/TyzoPmM2LbV7UKmOS4ejNGBRjqOK9JPR@n7NUyzHmWe@6s3/NUJf43780yNQ2nQf48DleKB5MTVONw1k8fBMjfSqjCSTTSoaVMDiWMctnxbWF8L3IY9DlyNqpJTZeSxMeGhxnxezah97rMwESci8Mi/xv0FfedFzUe5nAj7aDJ9/EqigizaGyu2kkxRqebY3U3eOUU@SGYyYJMxHh3rm8iON0pxZFKwExDQcBqfmm21MoaS1kOOQ21Grm48kjUhTGwq09nghw5vNKwZbSSGJUozTYgb0vlCSIe8F2IgCCYSGgtbbjWMPBKRRzGwGGohTJYfWrzRwKFo0028gscY3@MrbOyTmQvDJWZ7PuA5H/LC88PIkwgiprsgz0bTJDfBYx/cURTqll5knPZoGuJsJvE8NskbpWnxI9NtnOVeiPhEnFGEnOIG3iMfgelxAD0k33lViJ7X0i@yS9LnBojQ/a41ZFs4ijDoNJU0cR4d9bD6qCaJtLb4g36/i4uKJNhd0olnocIjX8DVlDHE2DKaJu3jxh0ePoMmcX4cImnsACFf4v6PsYc/OMP7rnHdBrUjAWvFCRU70KQtZ8TnK6DNLOf5qXCLDXy@KAqD@bN4JnjN8daDmPb7hmlpEshiPkg5Ei9qm7dvMV2Ox0JQURd0aSVJ@tbANs@3P8fl2jU9t6zHUHYhVntz2vLK@KAUICn0yOdAXC3oK5IUW/o1@dKvigAz7Cl29F8BbVoXeKuytAU9BgX0QTj1Le/CammSdGRFa7wIF0kZFx7x2LQ78Ew@dwOyFd7GjKd9/Qxf7QIKwy/2z3w12KSlsIyEa1LjxWSo6gu7hQgMD5S0XVz8pfUIPNXP8YGRelYASFlKscks0dKyyAvJLj2cZwJsoFqS2NJDhAbHDWwTaoYmqqQugOKrHOPE@N3xsZxAembXwEO@2qwM4OmXMQbCDIQrRbflQRJr4p@UByYKFi6hG2HNZIH7udRWoLlbng3cd4xgqhWKFss7VPDJk/1jdnywd/Jy62iXgfnw6OCr/Z3dHfb427SEjevgpBiWPTl4CtwlWizni@IH4CBvHUNMmTykreffZrtfHx7tHh@zgyO2/@zw6T5AA/BHW89P9nePM2z/@fbTFzu0uA4Q2PODE/Z0/9n@CQQ7Ofh/23u27TaO5J6Fr2gNJGKGxF28CgRtkAQtOJKo5cWyQnLBATAAYYMAFgOIgGTmnOQhP5APyKfkIZ@SD0nq1j09ICjSl6y9e9bnWBzM9KW6urq6qrqqOk296mqJqJ46PFBvqkd7r@BnZbf2unbygXo8qJ28xc7w0L6i3lWOTmp7p68rR@rd6dG7w@OqwoEl9mvHe68rtTfV/Sz0D32q6nfVtyfq@FXl9eu5gR6@f1s9UuQDYI1ytwpQVnZBVcWeaJz7taPq3gkOKHraA@QBgK/T6vhdda@GD9XvqzCcytGHtDR6XP3TKRSCj2q/8qbyDQwu4T6AFZiXvdOj6hsEGjBxfLp7fFI7OT2pqm8OD/cJ18fVo@9qe9Xjkkq8PjwmhJ0eV9MKr5@irqENwBZ8h@fd0@Ma4a329gT2jNN36M7gwSS/B8QAlBWouk8IRi8HHC0g6fDoA7aKeKAJSKv3r6rw/ghxStiqIBbQYWLvxC4GHQIST@xhqrfVb17Xvqm@3avi50Ns5n3tuOrBhNWOsUAN/S0@AOlAp6c0apwngIsfgVgTmnLTNJ2qdqAq@9/VEHIpDRRwXBNqIbTtvRKcw1rOJSxjSXeAtgH/2jagtO@@@hhgWse7lpfFthiT4GjvcL8KO7LkknKiD6ew62zOZT6yv8FOYz7Cz1iGmVbQmHTq3X57gLGiphobOK7DThqv4PBAPVfniS/cwiJ2FKqQTNbr31XqoOge1@te@jE1Y2A8VEOs3F8q5ckYMT88at5o4Hn5kvG@HUPUzpKcY5IfHp4vYEnG/hJ7tvnXgadyuVYg1TAIHxvWJqKQT0Wu8KQEWCPFMuK1FFGXZIGg310hB6ro6uazzTqaQdHxkQoNQvin/1P0gzcH6wVwZzZr5XKoxBIY3U@B7oY7odQG9I9kFui2qctsGAQ/dty83R3q/NnOYNByPU/XobJj0AM7rvdA9UbQmauema9PwNKpsqSVD7XeTSKMOV4WlCmZl@yIRubiP/Ux/fE0NJy7AY2i1BXZosU46S5xdXQ4SitJUYHREzTJKPO9qXxfe4/aXL64Wpp7/8q857WF7oCYlhY2vDOqd0F/Xl1wAVhglFMDUNKVTBe5nFVHu5OYwjdQ8AoLUd592quvAtrXASUgyE78nt0n7saj7tSGHvjwN0eVN7unBwfAOhHa1c21jfVSwmTJ@j7Nfz9gP5QulZKEDWEfBzmNPlmrZA8EH1opVoLtiPyJgHM5LIgpzPWk0UvM12DcMuKOSsjIcLgh3tHSRw88J0A8OIoSaTxNaHpduDKFANzYUD0czbU/JRHfB1mJaEB8VXozmrUp/oNtm@Wvl7gZkBCQkBglqQXKBe2C@J5zoD1BSbmhPDtYJOtoOuasawYHZOoi91gMnqVfQtvWLIbsqYjrlaadagIQT@ehUNptos8r@x3lCxFDLyX7gjffC73B4wfJR0fZ6fxwXBkfAxoPTE20R0dGZxn0mbR8sVOGKVpaMj1tK7TmewIUrT0xG5sEH9ZqIFAu0GewrOYaLpl8IPNdkoPr1ylPfWZKxSQc2E5JKFZ@A@UuGo60UtJ5QOS3zi6huC2TrISxdmP6SOgiH0w@Co3OGJp@FT6o/d8RJwva3waNE1qPsGXl7HsUJqlVxhWor4SU7o0@ULBOMSJs2q8@RM3c2hNzZQYmpzRTDp8BFMjszPSLD5SlsO0uQAASORo27PVrPM6ufFCdvnY8qY7nIf3m9dBVslforeJOu5n1izSJXWl9hoI/POWxrcnq8DVUVV@z4tagVQ8q05wqr56HDjfn6TweuWUygJgFT1R6xU6p85SVl1Wm@YCkTLI2nJbJfARi6e29p3PLyspoGeP9csKlEQVN7yA8d8dJSc0Hir1v4wkSOYn6CSWtw7zaqCbj5iMZ5hrkZ9kLsJ3nLTKG4O2x4xvcIHrcOmXWi1pT7nPyA8FOIqfCKC0gslsvC6ilbfXGQE@WSaRQA/1pn1PTB2zV0iWynL9DILSj4bPqjT8DkHuPGzaTWG75eJBG10TsjM0SUh9vym0OBiMQHX0cN8CY7s68rHovRoegH05Gkm4Q9rPuSCwSWuiHblBsYu2dthlOhE6ghd0xBiO0skQfNKTrAB1AOfvINLOuXCBeTaM72ujYna4UlLsdfdkGnFAWUULitlpXP/3EpRihkuEzIAx2Q6NckEsm9YPnDmb53QxGP@LejyJQvxW0TCJRq0myBfIk1fqUkrE55qEPByFZNGAq0AJiMFFgQ5rxQ4U9ekPISdyWnCiZJaYapZH8/H4MkWpnKOgoIlzpHYhvPQOTiVgqSiZPk9uzUFwjUBYpXLf3KmOU3DN@PK2c875hKS9ZiCg/16IjPjHfNE8f8EmM/OXnIa4eeINn2SKCIsAos@L56V0@R/BhYr733WDUsm2iIMm0/CGa30j1GfSJFrXpUNL3Nf1xGMxAA2jmutMctVF3vx1c9et7g57f6Q66PuhpmBV9yhwPH2f0iBPWGQ1uQrpFhz60rEKtWfTM6WM4nRr@NueSJSvFVjgOhq7tjjAezSpXnAWCLOfo46fMfkX0PZzPdWbqrK5FlRLx8FJytyt4pXvrvigsqswn99iAMLidOU8JDhEdU9yRFVtaulOg8aUCFowNlVG@d49DXgziLUARHcPEINbA3HE/sAeBmtm9EJ@1pukW5RIcYR6lYD/Ae2hCl16nfbxtFbjIV@gR8FIVNvNWVT5FmWI@QXyY3Y/u4sbvDD0A8CvAL7xYRC2LCIFYXFsnUwpZX5GkoAALef91iUcTJwYu1u3ALtSLNVqfzrca/zy7Dxvk4QNCkaTLu0OVuCJdUHzw6jW3DiynPvNwU0mplEdpOVAEqYzd/P0EGzzkHkuLHw9x2XKGjGlPWnYtoO9DVROwhLdsznnP2iBzCuSHV0yx@NhZm0NgeZFHmXXpg@toyYUCTLq8v@Kx1mAEzNiZw564eqTC8WCYeiT27uUdCzOsLcJ10/Me9PNlYivDZrncItSWZ/g4KyXm4ZkjmjjGyKMMaAjVV3o2ZD6PxGm5juutXJ89gIf7cBb5R5lNxcx3i9c@boof0WFXbzRmSRHsmGy0ZN6f1WHg9fs5iLTJ6lWdOEYdWUZ9xo9WU3NoMlh6PIaI@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@48iT@zU5cYn1FIyYlKG@GH3UZW6Qb0t@0OotinmWssYuj078FurX3W@ESWWXP3LidSVpOkv/frBasdUDYhk9qesczqUxWV9kARWB3d6HBUqujqPnkk/oFXaQVt9d3JwEEvq2phpP6PrYLSWz@eRhht2DnvtQo2WpO4gFy@da096vdzw5tvRd40csX68x74XDl5qBTqAGYE1EWYHow7f44AwQFEsnZEwVVT1J@22fWECHlDi3MGscUnJdaBo/@kan5fvTsj@Q03K/nqJA8TxXSqz@G58ljOlFX0KBbXRI/ijow/PAD34oo1u2OagihpDvqydmWDb8so7n3EDwXtIaLIoC7H3OfJOdl4Fvd4grd4PRr0W5gF4cjtf4eDArpDnInjASLG7k5CyzaZV8LHbs6KGsYhN6tic3pf0rRA6vTumuD8KOtXp0HXO/uzArgJDXsFhrmCa6bRyOo4nOd8f0SzTIYD9qNLX/tBtEp7mC8NOLws4egKIXhTSC1WfWBGPTGKCs4dLI1IXg5ulVAwwdI9EAZ2SnqaXRnJPcYNc53xaaCMO89yGwIQZVR5XAwPJfj@u@HHcbj@OKVI2f57YvzpDpCMAWoGy/ACfmAz7nzKwrA/m0oWwfIN3btzlO1ihjhUSiefN8l9u3Eqlop4NV1ZUpbILD5mMquxW1D6@2N1V@/B7F38vlYtrayXmufveZ3i5q1/eql1ogwycK82r0T78hG9ljApDZ22c4me58rN06Vm9vL1TCnNnlV0M2oen//nXf/@ff/uPXEV@/Cf@2KUfZ382hbLZbO5Z8/OzpdsS/j7bv0g9a5w9G16kOiWkMmT3p6PQ7/mW92i2mXggQqrV6zbui5oy3jPdkFw10V3ShX/KZdDAfvqJn87H0eMoesScqFF1vze88qm6ohZ2yqlKamkJnrbLqX9Oke1E3vvm/Sd4rzzk5ZQ0gVCL9/6oyvFerWanHUeuT9J7O8AcOXjdpeTLkYOry6S@LDBzprJZdZFRlwY8dPOoc8E4iKxmMjD/IkDq0ZFPDp1di9qAh9Jk@mZzPB9MXYcdku@06ZwvP/NFU3neeslnaNTGCjA8LF9iX3WJe8XhA7h47FXOnBXW1y4yyWQyYS5EqzeJzVFvQ@rLXJClj9ApPwOHYQ1hycDY6YK6MuICGkRkJJN0XdZSk691c/uoWpPGxAp3MmXJ82hvooEkDJtjCzcnU0AZCxU@uoJMhROKwkDZYPbYMzwAgMLrtolxKb4rORwGzW57Zlwe8EaKqHfYKzFkblm170TMKWfUcGRcT9tRg4AQlAIoVw82Ot8gI28AZbvE7XiM@jeIG3eJ6lKSf6tVmmDjEDQc9GadHnTmkitVeAPcCTDvyWT1@jqUDnvgmo0ApJ5AVjRPWOTLi3A3AjRF9Jt4Qob3Q/UwJxcLfHz8S9koYT2ghCP3w7UxFMTt9dmBaNCGR9jwMYqOj7CIDFdwSxWCQqUWlWN9v5zwgeWh56khl0Sswu/o8J3Ig0yQpA/LRXeSJoRPY4ae1MS320JpQ7zaDxVpyQ3qyUpyaK2Y0zeQKq/xrBLPKQEpWDJLd4kBa5ipy17/0oyfTzdDvI4w6@guuZsi@ycAxzLd6HB56o5jARw2rtLNY3jCKddlD8Kw2wBkwRBlmigFIgcPjKDV81SCOxNqweNARDC@Wh6aFWWPT5NSMB1SfD7D@wRNu31NBbGCeECKZ2IBnt1hjoOBsDz41R/0M8RyG8G422QHSu79qebFQzwXp2NKAuz@jkB58HGcZoKph3OdXUiOi2mqo3YITxisgOv/yojePuFMzLzCoiVwBAAyxGFm5zxCUtSioQRqII4UgZH8vwWDT2KE2Qs63XGsTloyMLDbOY/iVqMeF/klAmxjdw6zGCihT5oNS7gUfGvXDGS8@hsw2k1Pgp8X0Z4eDO5qfPGkqclDoni6zbv0YfiRBseGGlYwoA@Xbzo@Q7S54l5HSeQwlWcrTqoqmoUv9kCNC4jML5YpwIcaEG4xj5PMGWCjOIcNYKdzyyDiwvlY8xYBI3HbOznxqDn08nSxSHCHeWt60ZAiEdwmTEjP5//vfmNT2RhhfDIsPiiFdAB7dORwYvJozDe5cAXeBFpQl@R4wBpHE8xIx44ssqNgCpsuL1KrUwPHXFd66DLDGZKUhpQfBX6epey5nKuqxxvVvojXzqQ4pOuzDuxyLUln6Em8l3x9wpt5YX1Nt8sRW3T0Rr9udWiZRGYZhwk9O4Jy2l79NqIHHWLojiUzObeLSEPr8JrL6zGLZAHCZaxxaouOaKSc7RO0AEnsq1CZjAe18W8v01NuaTnrMy/pulWQC3wQg0VE8L2cPMEjeh97v5VagHygC4yA/df8MIDnRIIlD9EwnTdhZ3cwdfPpc@fcSRfWtzyH9GQjhyWbIWhGyWbA2dLwykbRPSkrI9m1PwbMwkeNbqsV9HUuVqgqvZlPdWn2DM35nw27C/mGW4eYeOBYvDzMwCTSC8E1PQ9Hfufap8e3g5ORP6vBJkQ/D/s8n8fY3hFsRngnE3054jVaaYGo4dyinhzRxKOGSF5RPkg@zTGJBpyJzxIXFiAguIMA7tOMP4wP1kKDPX62XRjpmfZNmNRLllBCdqK@5IOTywRf@HuNN9LW@R3QpmvdCCyP9GnummqREfCDdhC23nINFvV7eNIT9GPnEDp1sBAeXxvNtdKqBwSa1yrXl4cyYH/oSwN9eCmKzbh5Vb@e9MZdGdmdYelxYaX5u49JndTXVd9z/zGZDOdxZ40D2z3rwiqNdBliVBEWRAnTrVj6o0Y3jZ/MjpHQIKoKp/0orhJ95G9LX5gblu53tKqBWTmsAxutnOI4E5a6AbVLiWifVWbUT2PKB8IBSEEwlod08TSx5lt7jnGGMW8IMRMzuX8Nnf1vWcnlN3TaEGFJ66Xinsk8LNL1KaogrfJyiG1ptUApfPP44DoQzVbUCUt5tW6N42Sav7vC@oDmFpP@LFRpr21bdnkaW2gx4VD7a1roNEIM7cz2LNBYbWHEliSI5QwlMQLjWVq65aj0hWyDlRIoyTDPC9laYjIjXcDeoIk7m2faiBF3PnlaejMSEBUFmmpppiq7W7Sxib8vWvWiHUzDGpcpbZFdRRtoJLMuUMINGTyIqOAuogq/DFEM1yI88ZffDE1xBMSxdJtILCJfwzrENcte6yaC6A5fIsQ9NYLwXBsLBN1GD5MGRoDNNwcTqCX7LS0ML6tKB9hiXBZmx3A/esdaDyuQ4VzIuDHEcRjCZIRJdZMgXSXgf0xwDFzqGg06MQsIiKy5hClE8WGIDcK3sUZIygKVS3oJ8RnKJfmaoMJGwaNOHtETRuD@CvGe2SAexbTvBL/hhkIix7KqSwDhw7sf7XX3mKVj41tokgaOHBmlmT0vD4cYVPCQlTqXlFQWroLmlad@oYGabCVF3oPQzpNLJp4ACCxpYE496Ixqr4iBNwxgGCYjJ5tzIzcs1g@1ofuPZP/WONa@CkIBRkDIa@kA5TO6AponWCQECmSlBZp6HqYA1SZ2ZmEvkahG4iKhNkbJegcvyFa90CBkZoV26VBFN6iOxpZVcaHVVFuIVHJhNeViilG0ZtDRUdBEQ7ixUoWeZQ8Ws0MO2pYbuQEsDpQ0TcbYlT2cpSUlsJHJek7GWKjoxxDFcMSQcd6XeIs50gUmhC8J8bKlwDIxUt9wof2BC0iJaHUuLRZEkL1GckhkoclFeJ/0DeYXY4eqfgk/FAwxmIs3IpwQRzW5XyJoEj8XofP4fIBIyaD3t0OlP2smHkuqcm/3fbTIe/FGgfdie@@ZhTm0NuDug3@7TY7zpcDSaP9Ry3bw9RPef8lMAf8wgVK8wtgkEQBuH449uWv8SaTXZcNxna9NN@wX9ThxuWu1YDsGZksBTWnQE8fkg6QsPGsHW0ow8LM2TK2kc/fCCkHFRFDmNTOpHellihQzS/3VWQkIU20J434CzZF7EUVy4tHVoMl5AWCDwu9tygpAem2B1SJUiLjiGf6UmMonbU5T2JaVzCNQy3XpVsYg8NAgWMbaHfnjR4lY0ZEcO@yrPiaJAilrng7DbELVfr5I9hi5bPnRcllymWzay5F4tpwcgmzx4he28deV0yIDLbTjGMgdXKhkwCeVA1AME9RDD@PImC9cyz5y@@Vi3z/Elz/qxrD8hxdflg36m3EhZjkSYpoLhZiogNRqouGN6pnyxB5g2fZJQ14WsYf7G8T7g3Wj@xss7I9vYldROak8oG7x9YJuxzcDqWEIVTok@@PCjpDX8pq@dGRtXyr37oLm@Y624Rf/2Ib/vrfhnMEFZht9YKexpv4fc//3MPeYv7K3md/M13@zc1/zzrEJy5k7b1XKeaoKO19tnE/38@fTrdXDvyTHyZ1i7v0I/o6Tf0mubyb5ER7g1wv962NyJ7mNxdZvk7NcuVyGR2mlcgCt7Hxr2sRSs234Z2dNt7s@S@5kylT9p@TOOjwUikWA5Hxa3Tqfbubxf6f0RxI/7NMVI3zc1@qQctrIhsBngeIiT2r5IIya3LN2hxqSgFbH4wZS3Pmh0QwBjM4z0@JmXmQVICBO/vAxkPu3dNoMkR8pf8yYMppwxIVO@yC@elwJVoDpwoM/1AXt9iJ6RQkndK4JlBIioNXl8@w6Hl1fSg4KA4DJN0FiJrtyg3rhUseY3gz/7uS/ckw@ipdOLAlG/GxTdsVN2RX/N6mGs/HVoF9ckNU@qfZgusaB@iFkWMJ@dzgMxizxd4J@MKJUJjAcFHTwmr0mXkrY6/7I7n8vdeOqSQ3VfwjrHJvDDWWHM@U8@xpWVveatKJPsCr1M56Pra/qX8C48cI2jJPR0TWd7vhq0qALCU5Gs9r4kDJR5DCp@ZizUuRAlmvkrn10HKA0/iGQGJQAdjCa9HN0sRsIbBgrg7n3r/0fATS8TBaG1qpDMTT2/@jSza1hMKQQl2m77dA1SUGvdRwM/ZHPGevQa37id4IaZuKByQivHFSekuotBdeM7dTERlkijIMcLvdhZTh7GPH@MKXDPwm1SmG4MV3X42CcujAh4t1OlqImoJbDoQV0RXh7MBhH5Tlq3FSgn/EalI8NJolDQ/BwMBoRcHMc/4oGYkUpeUFwRD@l0@gFdUTQjFQXr9HAUQX9yTXRjrnW9qzw8kJy1pUL1vXi5PG6@VKulHccRChOkxibC5v4ZcK@l3QumZDUAWYcIFgzJFCQJ2RCp4XXoCmE4aDxAyVaQq4ECxLpL6u/ybInN3p4RGN3P@j4xCtuGpiMB962uiEVwJq5zieQ3RlF6RipNiadMMtrgQIrumE4CdY2NlcJINrxddHWoBkrWsxByyN/NMsRcFfj654Zxdb4SvWCj0FPvFcIbErny4uS6AxvNPMnPXJrWfeIdACVsZECFtytNL/brx68rpxU99Mgpqxh8ZDCkkxZ10Iuf16h7@0eZmpgMsIqvHyzjfVVJnI3TKe@Roscg/61jfYVG2DdQBhmcQ/oDt1UmaqJnwU3rIaotvc7aXMcTqmGdNZoXG4IyoSumnA0cvXKTyYxpCvEvpJIgrHEBlAHB6Yjt0c9YDx3Ct3LKwADwt3qY6DIHvJPpFxn@2kmY9bUS3rKAGPNZHbYyOLs9bqgeKaOJv0Yt03R2vFVCpgcHv8za3uaIr6QdUrqqox6fKlZzpdM3N5Hd@J9NldStxEKlxF3Mtid6flzJxKZ5gBCPPJy1iGT//1fKa90GyXR6bljD69eUJ/KOnN0lpl6le@qdVNhEyZrDNU@ZcfBdLzHmT7L45Kp0Bi0ZllKrtXaA6265X6y@xi63mfYq1dWmuXyC@8zdDkaYgbQITDD4ARa9Er4rh17Z0LEcufnfbyAehlD975/8/oVTDn6iQXh@OzPF8vPculUyvNKOAS/TPF9@4dv3qGVf@Rlydp/MBpcC15GvukkC7N9HZ7lLwj6tINDy@EqBM7ZCcYy@nB3duJ33oK05KZ8QAG6JVFgHExKd9uX@LIS@iahzIWXs9g4KjvxyXW8z50ylboaBe0S2ypuw/JHt@OVxvDnyu5iDbooF4vU@hgqldGraQ7r3T7s1q9O3rwup7Z9ha2WF6yK1ErDEAcQChGMi68qeB1VjHSAqxBVjTlajwgG/ltJOTvxsWzn/J1U6fb2Xnhecz5dEH5SEQG33ElaKG5UvjulpVFEBbNhUMYXvLV9Uz1x0lAXU7Dgyz5ubzNiWhzEWtZ9MLkhp6AtcHaMZcrl1aUleodVJmG5XMznPcyIcguthXh/PDTLC2tUuh355ZZrEOkPuwtuSypmizkOZAlzhfVifm3jq8EItogyXki/FAILKaPW8rE7ni2BbBiU9c1LSyAnw25afrq6vHnY3f3T91vH6/tus/FtwUk7P4Tktj8a2gCM/Jssi0XAY0eSa5eAwMjFpp8b@j8OcqutfBMkz8JGK9hYCzbzLzaba8GLrcbW1lazvbrZaG1t@BtrzUYOk71Tlex1tw9SksPkj922H9ftfYLZZjG/1W4XCusbrbWt9lYx/@LFamNzrZVfXW1vFvwXL9Zbxc3GVuPLUlsETwIYrOa7uHfMc@Dn9wt3iTu8XWp7/wc)

Main trouble in adding Brainlove was `()` loop on line 1. `~` is used to break out of it. Second `~` is for [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise).
 `~` is print command in cockfuck, so `8=,` needs to be inserted before `~`. Placement of `~`s and `8=,` is chosen to satisfy Pyth.

It is hard to push 1L_a further because x86 would be inside 1L_a,
so `^` of Pyramid Scheme was moved before `#CO`. I use `|` to send [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-98 and Trefunge-98 up, sole `^` is prohibited by Pyramid Scheme. `^` is no more protected by `#`, so
DOBELA dots need to be destroyed on line 1 with `_`. `,` is placed inside `[]` for brainfuck and its derivatives. Big [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik) "word" `PkPPXxy` is now
broken into 4 words `P`(nop), `k`(push next), `PPX`, and `xy`(duplicate).

````
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q8=P,k]PPX~~xy_)\(^'#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                       ...
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)[-'][(7     m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S  iii/ \ps;ddpsdoh#####]#######@@(~~####[##??###...
````

Second `()` loop is broken out of with `~~` on line 2.

LMBM marble from `O` on line 1 is destroyed on line 2 (`ps;dd`) instead of line 3 because `;` starts line comment in xEec.

Yet another place that was changed for Brainlove is `]@@(~~[` on line 2. Both [Agony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Agony) and Brainlove have `[]` and `()` loops, and both allow mixing them freely like this: `([)]`.
I don't want to rely on this behavior because it is hard to understand, so I close bf loop and open `(` at top level for [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload). `@@` and `~~` are needed for Agony, second `~`
is for Wise.

Main Brainlove code is on line 10:

```
)++$--![+++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](
```

Brainlove jumps to the main code by the first `~` in `]@@(~~[`. `++$--!` opens `[]` loop only for Brainlove, double `+` is for brainbool/boolfuck. 
Brainlove main code is also executed by Underload, it has one command `!` – discard the top element of the stack.

Answer (score 5):

## 281. [Wenyan-lang](https://github.com/wenyan-lang/wenyan), 13200 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退    @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo     anet/112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBq
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa


















































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu?1&&1Prers 6 4>8370::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>Exps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody/'='d  Float#  +- $2;#8在 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print(#~$+/ .---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce`  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @,,:1'<
#  |!o51@!00:8:8; ; ~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~-<~ -<<<~-! `=> #
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  >[};]+ pppppee^ee*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcxtLdiD4rJr9B/uSLPAKBQJVQIEECAIEKIoir3ivJKpF6up2gxBUKBSIEoEqqKpAAqKo6O7Z7XWPvbOenh5Hu9vj2/asZ@31RIx3Ymbc3rFnIuzXCcc8@QfIHxsbjg33P@g952RWoQACJNVtR@zDFomq/DyZefLkyZNfJ1uG3/3ZzxL4sKdub3zScwMWWH7A2p59Znkauz9m9wzbL@RXJQlDbXsnw77lBH5ZSjCdMcc6Z/uOabfBjQXuqeXYby0P/PKMDTz3xDP6LOgaAVhsiMUeWL13/XcBM91@33DaPoRcZeypAZ6doXnKjJYfeIYZ2K4DXmuMPXd6Rr/VNhiEsLyBZwUEvsAAhHlKcaZ9iow9dj3fwuRNy/dddFxnbNPqD4JxDSwlCGF4tvto@8mnM5E3GPvUgJwNetZoJi96jr2wLa89E0PX2RdHe3uzrnn2ueo6bO9q/vRV9tzzjZ4xC3@NbQ8Ddz@YdS@w7RPLMVhe29Dys55Fdt8zrkRZZ55ltDt2z9Jsx2Qq61q9geUxdGEd14MqC6xeKVfKNbcnMTUT45YmnjNgq@HDDO/EB0/3zAKjBTUxsK0263hunxmOfw4p6Ru5SXgEuzFNDiZkEAiNvfYhdttivmMPBlbAPaG4lkfekDLr2c6pxKnvqee2h6btnEA4C/A6GAZUJl8yIVqNDQQNa2hgCcICDwZZOHT7VrwufCBeyLU/sEy7Y5scOdYosBwfyutrzIa6O7d7Pda2ehBhAt3MMN9lQz/m1OoZXc3UJEQupsL6pz1mM3MwYNwLigFZ2suVmNV3X9vsLfj3uj4bDfrMt/vgHZhup2NZ7K016EJ01m8zc2xKbVdi8JiDmdJFtmULwjgWlHDn6dcBdwGi1OlA9tqsFQsHeaF8U6kNxwUUeswx@pwizMGYMABgohgd19XQve1avpMM2LnrnbKWZRpYdEzMt046xrAHKdodrBKgBdtnfRe@UJEOg2xB5ADxgbAxMWluQTCZsIqtATROrGIXSQbqO6zpc88AGvF8UZeB3QcKsYOkzyzDt5FrQRTfctpEHYOIn7lQ2njFszMbGh@gYugRbN/yiPwJLsNSAEgjolfl3LMDoAosxTZ7ahkeO/IsK8Vp1fJNY4CUGk8SEnMxhQALohFxbm4mdw/2kkCkPIZmDIAovdWjr30mGUyrsuVmBX5VWa5Iu08esIvlYzRzvgmEPPAUI8Wq75mfPT624DfSW9kT71ICqBJgpcey7iDIGuoAMqgGkMGsgUY0qWd5bdCLJcw2Z@og1nR4qDbUBjAC9kWGSmYOPQ85/ASpxikUuuc6J4BPKKw3dHiVF3NQBUB/bT/DrDMLaYDXkXtOGD7qAoXAPwSNcRfe6RBCoduB5igwGqbru70hhYOYfoBtErACURHifod9wTqG3cMo4I@geK49ywfixDhDp40137cdq62xMBvEeTxoj2eQnAFAyQFaQz/GXyhTEBgqwqWioteHX/1R@@QE4Gybpuu1Bbl@AcRuUvdoUGahg2NIsK5j9ChbEC6DqfPokMCZ0bPbxOkMZyySoExQqufusNdm1FDPbWhyXQMYrgVMwgwsTuTuMIA8ZljfOOVc0eaUCwXvGy2oWEqA0qZiq@zeDtSSCc2caEbtD4NOiamDXZb0sy@VrbKytXRsQeZSWmplOZs9qQDBaSvkBLbkdZTzxfZUd/EFOwFCGQ6wfO0MEAFz3HNBOLq6imRCnAfQZXvT7dUaWeYwsLB2geW3qCR9Y0yRY@ylQDCA9RztH2AVQT16Pddoizp@gXTinwNj7bKWAcw8QKaNeIrnFOND3rrIWxwfOjHrzRCyBDwJcDQOuq6TZ6rJZLPqQgAlOVX8ZCbptZIpDTsaJVWxq6bWsZ22ktyEZlQDnCVTFbNq1u1yozITPZ4HAHOOYJDTWIqZkrH1Hdku8qHeoItCBAR1/AEwUQ9LahpADj72VAHIaRnWIkKl7g1YBTG5cysJeGoZfkQY1MZ4G8L4KnI@AWHSJqabptWOtUxo1YDgwL/CXnsudvmUJ6xQ4AUOJmqcgFgHkXlBtnlBeErkMl2kU6AOB6G1LFZSWzZQNbYfYNKCiGNlg@CreR4GoHGqj9Uokgp0U7y/n7QArGmD9aG9e2NmWshEgJtYvIfARIbUoHwQZpnbYTk1XyhMN5orbSbwstvqN4Drvs1e2zSw8PHWgZyDdUB27hnOydA4gSbhOhDFME1rEAjOAyXxA@Atsx0IOaqiN9T8rrR8bzZt6hVCmWeSBrUfqj3RtxnILoQsroKghfIcF/BZGxqlSc1gOnUIcDaTuPwKg0xl4JW8IAthlw5Exls5NG4g4POuDa30nHLncEbHe5XZ5MEpnjqwarUTJY2Z0Wt385KWjZwwGwtBqFijV@FAb4mgalMOVPlxh@shG35/DmA3yiJw9pirljU0oL0bYPZdx50DFBAZgcUg0z68HkC0OkRJF3qiUI6ixhqJv1EVQZ0B14CWD/TXDYKBXwbGbwfdYUsDSskeeeP94MBBYskG3tgOXG5u9dxWtm/40D6zYQpZc9iyRzMFIreoDl/70hlIVB2fVRmyXqA6JdnxgW@S@w4GjnnJJOUQCP6WISAF0gBRSscnVrwHTOVw7JiKPEWUcobJ2HblFBgwYoSaz1Aam87ma3CazSUGi2dGy2KorO@ZZFBjQiaCx@CULenOVNFumUfpjizDq2P0fAu@zrDXQ@vQ4VxO4Z1/il1Id@4Aa1MoObs/6NmmHTS5L7t7VwgJbAkGbigHdVAISkGcO2KErAFDgTCi9@GhtcA9JOlVSUFB7lxOJWx5nuvxdIOuB506OWAwKY7UJ/bpsD2DVQfdEJ0yjiFQQDYDkHhhfMXlnhkimMbUbN/LkogpJBWMz5lmlckCHiV1hXTIFWtMFtGEkFgVWYtVoYI5ynC4EHgutnhs4RYv/I7bx66NvSDxEccDMFC3HZywkLhYQVKFMVeqiAQKkv6TSe21azvKRXJpaSlZTtZAXFha2gLTJpq20JQG0xaZVDJhOA1NFCNDJvStUwx0ayQv6yHkUaqBvGCEQ5y39kAx6uXyaiNj1HXxzeM3BUQG3SWEVvEDcJKpahWNqZRcO4eCaq3OdOl3sMs/ND17IJDwmXFmcLvAwiqhAajW9bAuKojz63HSr3qW5sPQxuwqXvK4njtuHF8ct9PHl8kMxk5VjGoLCgXpKX3txHOHAyWXqq@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@wWL8zgMOGLvirMdwG4c6i1zTh9bluD33xGUrEABJU9M4Ye87OGcLnXZgDKBF2W8JQdsnrjOeoUHLimaBi6tI8nxmCkNmKbz2GnoBNr/QkwALyny4/41d6K31Qi4H@Q9tOXqiQsagzJYRHU02CSDWNXpIN1iT37AG3bE3RU6@K2aBApoKpYbJ5@UMkJ8hV6KFv6Wo8UbOXaCdh17t0DSv7Ls0IMKpyMF4QemnhA/ebKCEiRlndA1RMQX0SoVP6hcZ13F2im@FVXemdvpuYGS/0IBF40vC4YFqM9nPJpeSWVXFt0xeLF9j2bZ1lkUuNYE82sWZmjmwR5ZlZtEXOzcWGuaiJ/RcgJpjeBx6QTH5N8RBFHO2/CfpNDJ2yl2UNs80dPJH3aElWWbXZfIxjK/iJZOhg@jabUsFzIP0i4OyKJpY45ICdwhj2rbVs/t2sE@rED0HB24aMW8NuZbw3QF@MwHw1LZgNMJnWyadDK4UTPoo54SHfwacnKD6AdM4Sj2rnV2ZQHvsul4Xp7Z0mlDJR6jvC4@s6w/aWjACADzWLvXvftjPPzl4sNt8un30sJod@l62Z7eAR7StZh9G8j1oDgsezBvOd@4C7diO27ehRCHIt6e9Z64bcOEBl0Ju9yQwYgjj0YPmo/37z7affV1kjnp0uz/sGZjH8vJMgAjGIYW5FozptlyQLZzhQkggXBzcP3gUQvns@aP97eaD3acHRzEwr4c929BH2cHpyaICfYZBmK7lOOoPeu3pNSoao09NoQhmgwPOCoOBOVNVeKvoxhPFIamGHigiY/eoqjinbeCsvcfyem5jo90ySiWr2DbX1tY7RqfdXsvrpUKnVMgXcvBaL25Y7B0FV1VrRNNWYOJTQjh7hmlA5umja2uhhAPjcBMklvHcfEW@12TOLBSs9bUNY8Pc2Ngw8uvtVSNfWres4npnLZezinqu0yrppdVrMxfLBopWE1ufpr@g1eFMCXkC81PgM9UceOZB1jtn7Xw@XzQLnY3VfLuQW2u3NnKFUrulrxutDSvXWVvV83rbzOvlMC7wWGAM2S5UGEqVDoimoZeqg2dKCjvTeBXTumm4sC4YzvIqsphBuDCOAwfhsYYeQ7EsDjBD9wK6h4viOD8l3Ivo3scl8YkkS9bIUQQsUUBcGde8Vui4gY7RmvjUajGwSsE/5/kvjiQgX@i5SwR@jqvqsfJd6Dq5nwWdzpRznpxPVezKehPnVXLma@rTq9misFe85gaO4K0RPL4WPxfeFa@5gSN4BQ4P1/Dng5vxmRc0AlYkYLjmPxfWjMecgBGkdYIU3ycw8SuR36JNAiKtud4LI0WwNwg2X/9vvvabKGo3xfI/UjNvIEcgiT1yQX5@ZOOiRWeqxUjRCPxYksNphOlZNPThskv2bGZkp57J8Xi87dvOqUvj5MjUzGl6AdtzFLt/2rsaswMjC3pNBY3yEMoxC3Ln91sdes0JgH3s7CwkedAUr@jpoWc1ss/og5O983IwPW09lXzL6gxh0JNt2Q6abwimbpQoZKfVshcFBUzg7onwOydYmT0bwsAzr61pejjKxWUiYNF8zvlo/4ACtgwas02vdbAp5AdDL4BY4vtfv9mGSrhaRV1jTEO/yNB0rHOsLrWzsMZEVLTQa37tTjp5QgyZbgJpGrhebPQiw3zQVPuq2jW8Po6wRHUDgeILKOEaWuM551Mv4Xd@ImVGSJ5eU2GO3Wfmlb00gesyH4bNk7qZWQni6dLwGhdhCSN8EGxbFMnDeuc1Yo34cDAm6kCfMyeHs/kLF2zYZMtD0B0GQ/7GXQ431ag9wN91rVWEzBWMlm6BcGy0bOua@veM02HbVUHGoyJjxopzwk5KT9N0aqdnnHJjE43zi88L6NknJyBJiO@iYOddGNXQcDR7Tp@bSMR3hv5AbUFlBdCGyEaton9NCl6PvxcFscVewMiwGGt2j163qPSIuIhcQJgjROP2LDWGNHsGzT2jNcZBevfjqQwTJNEG2E/VTKdzq9jhRUve8S1Vi@NjL0nxNzbmx@YbwzhK5g2ssnxDmMqnjqnMYovYDRULfZjdN3pqvh0zLmTu4aTxxDQnKM3YqGbP8IG0AlEd1hlUH72uI3fspEwYcHkT0zXEPslOuPNh0SK64GCiVZtuz/axafcWMdPZdcdJmrg1j16xyWh7HmLbJC35XTUyzecLrhngCvYCQrsFl@OLx7g8H6MczV2ENNM9x99CKaPrnln8Pb/Pezs3V7fgWGqPSMI253Yu7au9CDjxLp7mWX0Q/oGYaLZVp6Eu360Rbk8oFAdvrtYC7oWi13zkn84tTGD25rpPN5xwRiQ@nrtlY/DtnuuzQ3pfh0somO/z9/xmEEe7bTgqLR/FzfOjiUwNmCYmZRcQg9E7cXvF0knWgNdCihl6HexIxPe2LDNiebp@M8sL5SvX0cV3YV9xmvVOb6o7WsnwcINDzHhNtz2P74k1zMUFBBLFXUvzC7eXK1FMLcuH14sqwDO758Y4/P4c3dEi7Ibd0WBM8jqIjxhhowSGwOMy/M@T2tr1qbVvx9OugF2/qRCxyj3tWdD70ftKlbJ8Tv/IGHoud3sO1@kNraE1l8EdtF5buMH/mlHM7TOVE8VYFpOjOIGEU6NRqLdi/HmrXGPHj7ZrGQwwW2jkN4pHc/ndAAT7AY7Qn4LhKRquRjxxhoOpyp0aBTrPrsdcdxC2bLc9lUn0@ViOVLpZCJuS/n2LftcOzvhgEpfCqmu5XE4IRbHp7inLdYO21Sjua5u/pxIml0nKk7DYc3ox4/w0JjOvUPX2qa/iHOjtuFN@0YwCBd7YyDq2YwVjfN@S0bZct/cxtQf8tm2jvAdSLC4R3VSLV2QpsWmOTaZNfJx0aXUWTZjwvkiMZgFxOGa/jhDik7S3qmEVhRtooCcz1uunkGJTvjelAj08zUvxTRa9xYKqmIzRtZK2fm1j5OKv27J6Bv@MimvXwdvQVq@FF0krQq6mVTBcOeNrZZO118QMyxqMAVl2GwZFXatvkfWa0YTRfj30w8/CQCMXf3O8NVqZXBRvYAOPcPA9tS4Xk6IC14FhXGB4JxaOg3q4fi5cF/HlcP59LnL3@8aJxc@UXcc4J1MjuMOajx4nxvmTJGW@P82EaHyTyPWkAI3p1Br74XcuwMdjE@pz2L95lm@m3Zu0pemmhq5l5y473CAmOl2363StLt8zFNkWNQ@gyICfBryuEJD/k67JiD/F9zPFMdtze73bYBb5I@eWrtuZm6ddPKPWhqgfBXdstMBDfG6cPYRunhBE/f2idtO1htBb@W7gDiyVbIuC9nByib8XcdFwGejnnbW6dkYBMBJ@f1745k0RTww3GAzo0xz0hj69KKpKRwuvGbLxqXNKkuiSud6J9tbttzThqO3x72Oo8AXMpoXnXHALE6ds68RtmV37pky3LCNw7NNsOMfErdcOewcxPNlMfYDOWs8G9HpjDemlGvc/xM/@okoX01W8Y4sM86mgzHaGnjdGSg/nomnKgLZkTc4sT7jK9P6MaLKYL3egYVGuxMrjHG@SIXDnXrhD7Zo1F7FQuZAsSWpHCV21ciDm6Avnraa2j8ba1Ooqfy2SpmbKT5mKrQ9/zMSr2FZBU5B2bH4Y3Kdoamqxe24X53SHJ/5VJsmXBdogmOFrbu1vn@Ap8FtUPq9o6MsMR3wW1UG@l8X98vBtQm0OrWuXeArXrvFQOL2nGq4NnyZ8oF6HCyfsevbA52@mdvJzRY@ry9ZXQ43nj71FnbWtDl@FQdNNMmPf9fDUFggnqulZvomT@MjbuSTG@ZjjngCPV3tsEjgMO7cIV1fK55JE1HeqXz6xTgzc0vnIxt2dvTmUAlBnF8xvAvq1oeHbXxu6gTUX3uyi@U3gHhsntvlwCvMhsBCjYt8f/0w1BXS6ivzzru3TgZnQcM3EFRIZJ1uksyaMHOYN@WYWCqLj5dfPzcRELrHfnKn7LNyXHhlwqQL9jblpzVsDcAc0@ByT6brpfzug6V3xnUtV8zceXJf8@bA/GPriMz912hsUnxzvn5K7f24Dq1TfAIdmXaMXzJ9Aj03vgvQmOtOJcZE8/w27556wb5RyDIQ9EN5QvJ9DcPehW39qBNAinDkETGkv4OWzS7Q4c6JyLum/AZqwVplqO3Zw/SxREBgw2gq/WBjeAeGxz@wjfGv3PhaCejQfI4@ulWRBBhibPVQrwPfd@azlWdCFcmUG0Ra56zszE2jxkA7/ozHSPxCnfpGYtROuVoh@x7HO4@O/axedytjZus4wUPF8wbXL6ZNOpnhtJ1Nmo1IxRitM@dru4@epOMnQHtybRFwLxphDvzeemBZuh5ihRNsBKW8xc54OHQ5UHlikJeIZ7Ra9Ic72AM@vUR/wwJ03mHo69qzg1qMx6FGG/QeWiYugN6b9xH0M8h30bQPgwv1nFj@eNsVc5kfEaI9c0@gBfto3JnNIYOd0HpNxuzGwWlC/vYlpvsA2D/ADIzAWCFg0HUmDy8h0I63YvZblvaZ5xph50Xh5OkMPrRENXBYTDG@QamCaXCrHGb@p5jK7YuQPXNfhb@LKOfjoj6/nPtBf0Ov2i/8abqKe6g7njv@mS3sQqR/gRycXFdezWm6Pv7EIC3pCx@b7HAzPtvzsI9sZjsituMZUEOfmj5D4buKctk4qYKAhhUus0TZj3DUneOfMMAzk5DPDpx0I8wc/U1uab7/fqWt4pourcsLwkWtysbNpN7D1aM823ynRgooZAVMzzKE45XRTVnv9Vp9eCwcvsdp@ZrXw7F@LzqYGxmieZDl9hk04zpwiC9kaNv4iU57C8Ch184zZ7NhuGuP2gF7E1M/nEkqY3BPbMt8aqVuNq2ItiqasswYNgec2qulteiAD9Sw16OKmz2xw3Vx6eD54zoLMsG/hGvj0StBCUnL9LtGBO3/VP2K1niV2juOuRWj0oRn5rbq9kFARPPwf3P8sC11ys7iG2hOGI/UEGNnN@wwg80PPEZ/bENtT1w869uhggHqxXG8RZ8FiFSAKfHgjQNPKokJA7TnDHp8OOYltK@u3aagHgmHHBVOPmHdgqZZzppK@qNHVErkeqbzJbqPCtcBqq2KCBJc11EehXBYFE985a7lxNom7WvUsR@youCb2uc5D7rkfrUqChzrw6Zsd@E/3Hx0caQNfn9sKwmlM3K04tHu4ykgNLnQDxJDpivTWM6hxbJMn6R6aOveWL@ViM2avDS@2XMt36OG5xOz9Q13debSvYYAFdcSXXFT44HLi1GfxBo9B12hZgZE1Fg6z0NcK5ouYD48eP0pPzmkzZafruX0rFffeOTzMAIdinx3O9Y7H3oMW1XFHC6Pv7@p6ag7JP3doSXMRc52T0iJIRxYMlqHCHvIjwzeKZ6Y7sNpH44H1BfS9yOD9WyZfXFjIJ8aZfYItl20sRBQ1brahFddSse3rlofqycLvovo8tQfIYU36ZPln4W4aFDxWs97qfOHjug0Ls0IQy4mNFB8XSc9dpdbAVqFlnHTRlDX8XzRjuq4vwvOh0YF6ZYWFlTUdYJ5g0nPPbrHcbYnhjxo5qQFQlWrfuM9@Xe0Du8/iC1cPhCMYWwt38VwHIHIuzm3w55YzNhyV6xFYLHiI84ak6C3SIAR8j5@EBTfbE6pGfC3UWiiODZPwFY7OwdEwzSFOKEOD0BgFVBQjnU6lJBHrIYghfVSJhpF8Ov0OJF5hudCIuexC30LhUfmJwpYNtlmFEKlUhWsRAh4J/cXQqrCOHQKG/sk@cSADYfqk0Q15Odfk4TMY0Qch1HqdLV@MyrmyfomKRcoyazR4fvGhRHZHA1LH9oxHry8bjepyUlWTy8ljp8xyySi41fOt@cGNqbCQWfyIDEfY5aoaXdKzGOGywpVfgUiJmuK6htOGdi84J5Tf4yqcuH6wIzwk8We/2xYK9EhRZN/2jR4gBPVgAhPvuudbPN0QXYOB4ZE2NFLR1OPao9SdbaFXjevNg8p6vndUEsq7hNJNsDzlKw5RLjjd4GYJPIsfcLLguYnOVYuEo1hhoUy3N@w7MJhpB11fY4c2HbMfepODc0IVqRN4uCLazrB91rZwEzppT6ANAD3XPY3E2z/7Xa6yjHQoiLPtYfKkezCWIqpK0ElPmGm6Q8h1COSt5bkiiIJINsxgiDttSPUluadQswDpUgNaV0NNYpQMVye2s33I1F2WRIU4qM@mYneU5e1nn35RzzWq71k/a/3Xb2ZTFwJx8ifQjH05w8IglUskrLh3AbwnvkkmL49knmCkYMIWMyjnvD5QISgnMtQxEdKY6w7CZoNDctJmGFGjUCqkoJnqOdyz2ycFf0Sw1jmpFKOTzA7Ke6SZ1IcGBtYUgeatrrqsDPkOEPUwYAVIENWyGVzBn4sKPe2@heqxMMryiL1jJHgB19cLObBxRPZQI1u/ej/kdqvxQ2PZB1ZrSMcnzvJavlCl4iw3q5s1MoHk76Kqw/rL41E@px6P1ncbWT9E6vHx6JNc/kvAuutBrLtZbHm7Tx5cLGu13Lt3vjFmsnyZrPBDbsAmli@e7j/dPTzaPnp@CLVwGTK2PX7UNeQ1SEV0er3r9kiJJOAFh/sfwX8i24QJoqriVEqKnzOmoALXsiovc2OMNU3FviH6vPi@FfO/GkDwNOiNpKhfACowiNgQa1h4riqSibhC@x9RmR2QxO1pEWLwKOEcXkqoklkVkKUCsm6JKra4sFvc7TYYuxHK9WjbmhsEMRalV4/8eRHnouDy76XcA8P3f/FycyjXl5vCXFNuCBq5hnH2tvcfPX@2Ox0t7OSJ61Y3CuKAPWfO2NL4xEGo7pD02oiIuIOmKjOZInCr6My4FmUrOLegWII5mn0emSiU8i9LE8IEzFRRmXdDSCGKQjlA6QYFkdnz/zCqj2Ux7KNj4C54ESMmsCdHoMOMa7KAnCCl1Bo@YTEQqkBX2PSeEhMX/Drpx8WfTNjisGjYRw993uYWdFVRr@Mz@I/1SqEp32AjJrozvcFUlodfz3JOoMBh2FSF91FsmSNCXuZ5l6P8oiJhyFP7tUFLzTSEFufmoZfuGQM/FAUT7IkbWGX2ZuiSbp6QmUTyBemwNrjub6pars2adP7ASBME37DfInj7e4dVlM64aEb8PU5zQwc7KgjEVXAL7RmBh@rquVoDrguXo9wVWlrDrpJmZn2hlTGSEnx2Zvs2DDupEjoo4/SAU2JpRMFRlTtpZWLbPR9kkjZ03yChBNjVgnCi0WFrfuJadZicAJrUIpExw2QJw/rVq1o7oSs9x3HwKx55mcIRZD8GM7m5pKqAuRPbCfW2l1GRO01KllngDXFzdC15JUqYhTKZ1G7Q78UCzlFIfGxlP/zqj7gS4uMAzN8V5lHuPth@Wdg6YP6V0EfXwfbPIlsebN/jtpdZrLKrilon@YzUziw8ng7EeU@@UjBkDKEGeypQVOVY3V/sP2W@iVqLsUL7xihWV8hmwnEKs/tAGWdU0RicpzCpxwkcpf4F0AkQFxAJyjgo1lB6ltdQUGdnOZvFjOMKtEa71K0R3xxGKjzfDFEXNUhi2WKhuKZnIZPqWQiQFGud4ElbDjCVKgNjlM7sQfVVy2Sbm5tM9k2jZ1WLFU4g2WXj5ar8KsroMoSV@GihziAORJnEAL@aiKYsG2k9hVGxN0vqSWRsbZfTG4iEChkgSAqdnVAVD8icrkAVELMDo2wSm8bhKAi4tuPGtESHgFQAxGFz/crTbXJyehZXSGKtVItXg/wCgx1isLI8j2LrL9lxcOw0hOZsBtT34zn064D5n8xRp80pC1WNXVX7rMwqbcbSsHuHjouLTXuQW6bks/nVrF5MxShUFqAgv9je3wFIaOHAMUzLfu0O/O2d3f3PDp4eXtGARyGTs8GSLFnbTB@rWqbeiAzJKN/TSL2/lz18fH8vRGU8V5NpEgwxORowm815qc3mdEHqL/hB5atpk8eVhPTcbQHTvlt1j07XXIU@8c3GAu7wc5JXUlVSF5f1xmbt2ElcSf7dPB3tCW0FiQtMxz5paE/OZhOzGN3JcoR3svhaqH9DR@UbeDY7cE8nqjyEQ8yDBw@hAAeQtGwYahHzhAwc8Pmfic6pPL8UxifWx@eISNF2lKNYyKPw@hhsWhMVqUI3aNfwuz27JUEH3kZlwVyzV6i6KtIJpvmDnh0oKUmokwVRAlW5iktkRuWRRttWlBQ2c4KVYdepGw3hpSRoBAAv@XTod9lTdxCb2XpghaZnII2wB0O@hcFinw37EK5Dn2cWzeGCfKJCZEBUMsoqH1VDyxLaRkdp1OgK6dVR56gouNZvF5RRSutao7Z9AgxcSWWgpX@ig1gV6UPBQpMGUicJPI5j@FM8ahpH6UcpnR1NgBt1Q7OdtjVSUItauQHyKbonz1@cJVPyFRogzbc7oa7MGRW4YUM0AtEiJupjZxrbRnRzzIwq4Y0N1ETXxx3RVQYpHgbeIzBC/6R0@saAKUNSTO0zjZFVOVacjB94KabWuHonh6XTNKqGD3mA1IxBO2QiwmEKzkIq2SrUDrr6Ths/b@0Bq@ua1gAzJZJiyzijtgNdOc5FpSQYJUGUMoGtYt2yMuaIU6/GKQ/ioL9EyiIZamee400qhWl5wkVcUKlZ7W5Myd6kBXKsbmyURW1Ms5oNBmRxlctrWQA7h4WEUirgV@jrAKzhBSJ40wyulAJbuPe55TgWIAhopm9AH2wMgci8VCa8NSozuXCCUkjwLD4UCkAgo9MXUewmL3q4kWY5W6HJmcol9KmvjrFT7YhudZz977NatnKhLPeq4ywIOqmastyt6unVlXR62VlRlh3s6u/exTmdy2WQJJoaDJFGEEhd7qUqQM8geVSXncqysakst6v5FYoBVhikXUCE935Wu1g2LrPLd6GnzoCLxxuvsuyT9t@cpumXkD9sIcvZDNDMBSpLpSujMPllO53GPGjLTczA@@zxYZp49vFhlqaPKkIazZ70RXOb4apRTVy5MIsjUDiLigbGnkfGLs5RNcPAqE8pXESf47dA9uAJf45rK4yWcS0/Lv7L0z63ZyyC3yVJMSPXtczVLwMCRwogEa0ZI5UCZvKznyX0IpOV5a3iau8snSzkKvDSKwVWYJ8sH6tqfrmeYIl7yw3DCJowcM@uXBw/KJ2cMauTL76p2x3tTan6NHPaePr0y/fN9y9H49SxkkzsHLyT9TUIv8426HfbZ53lFzy3VF2YWMlKieyKfnc9m3316hUIvfjUa1otDKI13r9P1ZON@jqWaRGgpJLPpw5t286y44HfbsOv4nYZXeLWSPAnnVZUcoGXWuduW1v9UQcNo23r5GS4a4y5u50Y4mcvEHEff@PFixdoeEEPe/uMu7MEh8hEuHLTKCRYPpf/s58sXWYunjY3/@xb/ay1hJ8D/Hz38jGaD/XCJ0tLn9y/v7aWAWxx89NvPP369vb22oNM4Wm9sLWm5pY2//RPlpby@c18dqnh@3ojWT/9Us7n1mTtz3472Xz69Gu@jxWGzyrTwYjvEvx0ViiwU/YWntMOw38yv23HzAaaW523LPE2oet6Ykx/TVxnwIF1lZjP9LPE9NrW@n/7/sGbRJCo5bMvPPgGiTeJYinBjWAA22poO0vUEpsYrHiZGGer1SoY1//bv4X4tc8ADvqMN@FVK4SwiuNETa1SlHeJWhEMej4P6f7f3/wm5uBeHR55bT0vbzXgWaFnU0rURuBZq@3vsXwtvyLIRy/d1e/Gsu8EXRBAjhN6ae3gHllty6Wvg194DMcKsrqeP@bkyamFf3EeJTFx7gLOoK6Zm5gOSmbhAuFfJIhugHCIdrhZOBA5cYcXs@FeHBvGynp6LX/PqbwQT2T4h3ue4d2DxaV7rx5ks5s1kAHwKZfvHYdNL8vWS7Lr3sNpQTZCpFfYowjBNTlXysuZTOYehh@p@IwSEwwyjiSWmEJtgk1sLO6UYGE0NgnzseF28fnzf//nP/jz79PfD@j3n6REuAFOrZ81auEDNCTXPPniWFhHUw@wpsYzpuc@fZcsrCYPwQQNR498JyVKJGo1fNG/sJGJvjNuwqcWWSjEJMr8cEywnxCpCSnxPptlWCXsLCzOvaXyUqlcLOezTTZTkntQTXJ@fUNu1PKF/AFUnS5TxW3EQgGH3Npagj/6hyey4nuJXIQzBbn6LLHarZ9Zti4l6ol6o8Gbdi1eRzc9zzS1ArSnkaUZL3fiTEqowMjS6WdA2kyQODzH6Ruf52lNawozGlz4uqrqAlQp8Q/w1CSWuICn8X6l/n4lTLleE4ZNtVFLiwzBR2vea6TVy8u69jJdqYh/kBYrkQ0f@DD4QUEal6q6@RKA1afBJtfcZNG9h9A5cHprzZebAD69Wd@sujv005qIXbXxslbfnAYhMnfvXlqDWrgHAGrLDZYCUVRVl@oLywAAGwqD4QzU8eXmZe2yvnl5ubkJ/5v0vhRfcL3cvPJPn8mzIMzEv4FUdVzP1o6zorXXGmDXsjV00bLHYKjBF8JBnyMlLpAgWb2h4vCqqtb1YqFBEgV7zB7zx3HgH36hFV3Q4TG6Ofzl8BBhmMiZu0iJFWCy2bK@kl/NFkafFHfzwKl8TDovy9kVNLzD/h7EtA0pgWOfDT4E2iCHVx@@@t/xd/zhq98HK5QTL3Al39Yb/Hv0Fv/eBPh3ZOLfszf4x47e4t@zAP8et/DvqY9/R2/wb7uFf0d9/Lv/Bv@kRJUxkEWXt3K93FlOP9VPwWCzHAwFurmu3gbOyHIWy41zY5bru3obTBb85cBk5zosd8JyTs7RdfAEQ8ByAZo68DmBvw5A8eDPzuUQeO6MQSo95Lek1p6@75osdSzVWfKVBeKjpms5rWg3G6giC2TGSiJ7fJzlUjXLr1VIvdblJWs2d588aDaz2GaPH7sHk/@Dg37ceu1//8B9fOD2Xfg/ODh4fAy8t5a@l1bvwVOtpTfFZytRq2wdl1Wk8bA5JbKbW8e1VRXNxTS0kDy6pT/ymUCEb23pWEqeQw9@XiFBoXJ@VjmvkCGyckNTBBDBuAFiVYSAAS4Q7/hFlgSCc3jOCC7Z0HgOnqGJG7Ivzo9RLIaBUPQP6Ihb/x7@7f9v/T9@zpR6IwVt4OJyU6EnhX@p1MXlxaV411KKIizKJvyhA9gxysVlDY0U6AJMdSXVSF1ecjd4K6lNDrCGaWzWKPIkIHCjRJQmpctfyt/vF9Pmz3GyAvJxdVkR65vHx6NcLlVpgUu0yGG8o6WyVIU2ES23cHkThsV6ikIU1ioVfYWb82v5SmVNWNZLlUpJmJcVZePqU8tt6UUQY9bWUqlKJSfCwgC4EhoBhOUbZgXbeCWRwszyhq/kcJqV7i9KymX57l1FXPe1NRik7t7VN3Lv3kVOzWbb9ppNdF99905uyrjfqLpRAHuu9O4d8JxkyvWUJy5f6VZUnX2Sr1EKG64HpVoHb6Zn85M0u4ZvBIGnvLUHGRm3jftyiu4cyOVc7zj50@9961vHySruQCHXNR0BYCqssLlZXKvVimtgLpag4PIy39KknKQ39NTlclbmxWXycjIhvPTSeopcL5PozxKbbKsGDdXHh11cJqj@2FohpbTGVuoCXEI3fWODO7K1olJKb4i/6lKK1VaY@MPx12p6bWV95R4OwEbzH2StlQujmsxmk5fVC6OMk3KXFVPccIMnPI27d1c3AKWlXOVYajYfbB9tN/GqX9xyAP0sQ0fi0xIuJw@8ZJ1mUAsbjToWr3GcTJYr96jy9VKBJZIVEU5NAstnpQ3O7xO@L9kdPOs9IrAzv5XEgOnrq9DrQqcrDWj713qOtXEF3WNup7MEjlCFrIWbHXyr1wuvBTp3vV773G5bS1Li6aPtnd2jTH4T5IH83vZOJn/4/H5CR2thYifvVbQ/291@cPAcIjx9tLt9uPvp/he7z5@Cuy@99t4almVYQ8tqng@H52/Ya9tu2oC93tC2bdf0IBNNy7IGECx8KpbFLNP2jdevDW9AD@NM@8OPv/Phx//Dh9/63off@s6H3/rBT7/6wXfg97vw@x7/fu/fbBTw/dOv/tnvfPjN3wLH/wS/P4LfT3761a9/k//I/sfw@y8xtz8Wv1g4/pMA1i//9Kvv//ZPv/qVH8LvX4rfD6/@fvUn838/@PbiH8b7/u9cH@Z7/xZ@v8dhhWG/95vcDb9Xwv8mD/crP/zwa/@O//@p@EPjb334tT/Gl7D80x/@6X/58K3/kM@X/vRff/jO9z58@/sfvv2tD9/@7odv/@P8h1//13ou/vqdDz/4g7/6w9/7qz/8X@j/d@n9e7f5//DDf/oX/8df/Me/@EPx@wn8/h2YfvIX/wFI92//4Mf4//0/@Ns/@jH@/2//6m//4F/87S//r2T4ETf8P//y3/D3X//qf/6b3/juX/3km3/zL37yNz/6g7/6P3/l//r1//zX/@Pv//X//C10/NFP/uqPfvkvv/Wdv/z2P//Lb3214P2da99f3cL9q38Al9vn8zZwblOuj3X56ufKzy@CjUkqQCd0rw/Lg/h7f2yxipRjOcZf0E5/8E8@/PovAfn/GgQE2/8ENvjnFvD6LlnYl18ib4z7szRN7ajpL79EfzFc/xJsiRrNyGEvUcqX0isgEa9sbERTdZsTMN@FGO@yIMfn7r0DEF9SfP6wL8NgkLffoGAQjolgYbjpTFIY3PfK3X/61T//bfKI4qLzL02BzIXO8dDLGPxdiI7vIm@YFDce@rvIXj78@Jsffvsff/jxjz78@JexP1HXNjLbGZAKrp/3hoCFW4TDgMXbhIOAOo5p2RJbkvJgWNrE2VpJT796BblfAhMM1lakwirYJL1GZh3NEDENNsan89L4hn9pbYOhBVxG5Apflgav@2lWrVbT0qiKk38YFKwYZ8RqJZxhwvmUKsDFSDxOplmCcRAb3ScoELOafsaaK9URj5hGhxpBQLqS0OmZrOfldKn6ABKsjh4whIXA09Ir@L6q1krVUQ3BvacsAIz0fUgSQlUxd6Pae7BXCSaEl0YP3kNWStV0ulYClyoWMk2pZZqUpl6gwlHZ0ywtJjbhi/tPt@4x9omsl2Q@BQqoZCI0vtOT0BgQgoP/cXpFFIf@QyP9VjA@1NOI8MPduP8WOlN8EQDgqipuW4SfqmJu7oH3iINKU7LwSXMIgLk0n@FikQMJOWkpTfWbJgukD3n46AdAbtYkXqDl5WUJrfKq3DyAASiM9LzTsh8YHi6skhRaZnJxQ0Zn3AUWFhA3Cy4/pfHqyoMVeOvwv7tEO7upTJUVaTmJsytJJlL9JM1/9@6tsE8AB/SduElMTa@6a26CF3cznZbzkHDNBdsKFTVNgHCugv7T0suExBJEA9BoMvwNH61K7gyG8iK/5PCyKmHO8qs62nGudTgcYgxNy2iZjPhq9CUHTRg08hVfbZmkTX5otIenPsI5iQ2JD6eYXlyjIz9002KKpaSEaaEYx6TH/sl9dwTDmIwsZ/Qirs6lxJTQUTmPrVjaLefg/XW3XK6@19fWJfiSfYg3PoozmEBPXcuztM1NpIvahUqTYGgE@bco1WpijwLTpdrh7hEEPzpgej6nMRgCXayt59cKa4X8arFYWM/ra8WNtWKhtAoct5gr5PP6xtraRmlj/XI@d7qXycjrRXmz9o@uPP/dP5r3zHfFR6p9yUYaLjuol1KtV@XbZpdx64J8nJMrNDdHKF2u5zL4l19dhTdkOaMX1htLS70LFTFwTHs1L3BzCORaulAZjBjvwMOkOxK7A07wQBq4eMvEdpv9g4rYWoEXWPPtFbJeAEqHKjkGUufgpEH8qUzZBkAJFxcXsZ@UWPrGNwJWq8FgR93fkxLQhrss3Gmg2m2tq9E1y@2hZ5HvCWNt@wsb75LR2rY/6BljoNCcJiUuLy870SoYWXmMNr4vTXJpgflyZEj///P3/eTzan5VXdVVfRX/bzDk8f/24fPwn8c3xFrNS5tciVINL1l1jXY1uoicKamLdrXtmnQArNKp1hsaHj@vtLWW2x5rfjCGAbggm2qy1XPN02ToaePtbHj2s5o1slqzCXQXuDAqp3H8Vn69UF7KelkNN8crHZbayhfXweXYCZ3ApYAuL6edNsptLczRY2ghEC9fzhcLl5tCx2INyoP5qmEuLkTmyo7rWJe4IbpsdIBzXph8I1FZzhdKcqVemdiBuVQal/f6Vts22HEOz99dzI1YLMqXYThIGsf0OOvClD7eqIQ77cu541xqQeQcRIYsU06lTaG4qUZbQ@rAAht4r2y9sRmqdKpJ79@/H9FurPK@E4htWfm1ErozCScR7oKgdVfnxkJxYsyh8QjVbz2BugPG7bBHeLoicNmRy3fx37fMBSF2ugZds7vjub7/C4S5bzin3OuBzdX@RF4PDbxNwO/bQXdBiOeDPh6Ytbx/MAi7/RZkEGmKB7gPL6/nuvMCrLPnTxeU8nGktg93cJHePgj@bP/Th0ex79Hu9s5DqcjuHzx5MPMpiEAF9mh37yiyrnPfMGohAvH13UePZq3iA1JChaa7llhhHXdwhxbo5Y3AkOU6GzUqCcBLcAlCdaXtDLf0u3f1px4ekSiytVppdT1XLh/nKpdQpOr90/IA94L71mDFr@2OBv7GGpSSDdlzwPt5BbXPyDK0xb3tHWx62WQ1Ca2B9BOhTKWy5XwlUfrr3/hdkENw8/iGzk9C2r5Ex5HxMle8uDmQUDdQ2z136JBnqze02HDAFjrCB53Q6Nkn3YAF524YQGoZBoPfxz4Q34o/wfUOAU@D3K749OYEx71KdoflJI1kt/xGqVDaWM2XMqWN0lpBLxYKGT2f0ddL6xsgb@T0kl4sFTb0TGltY3UN5CPwLWysSwmQE@xONgtCqS7L8C0DWMfEC8k28WY3V@vWpASfkGZvFSPFEkZkHzLZgjgy3oTrB3Q@ZsWuyvk1PLwGQipANJjJEnt7O7m9PVm@jxZcLtvJyXIbLYVSLrd@X5Yt8tkBGS4vyy6PU0LVBXLALbnc/R1ZHnIAqFlQlrto2S3iyFmWbbTsbO/tYTodtOQxPgQ75T7c0gst6xDMQcvqKg29ZflNBA7CbfOE1iinu2jBNNFnj/vsgJ8sfxrmJ5cDCM94OA7hYVjW7W1Z3ueW7W302aGCF3hWP0fLNj2y7IEFiFCWT8Bwgv2BLLfAiKQoyyaYzLEBbnj5GyqXc7ARjjmCEEWyPKLQhnkqwwBRuGMyDx8@NLpB2zrhz9jjX2hu@@Bjj4a7e61PP22dnLS88fbup8/QZ2fnodEZD73WSUtEazXhcSEO@Jz2x7MP5HG/2TR6c30@Bx9nxqc5blqYt6bxBvIknhNMpN/cAZ8d8Jk3n8@hwdOHoC187vfhe99okU/4kA99R62WXEFCRe0OOPuObebUAV6Q6Rum51bQPqousaSSzIzrxVyjQu6sr7DUBbAv9O8odJ84DqpAwr4Y10fVXKM6qq7nxSE7RT4e5Qu2nFnqb@kbIJ0YW3p@LT0q4/0TbifJkqq@peh3V94qT0AQWV0ry8dbW6pc1xtbeb1ULq6/XBnKcqqM763V9fJbGGclYTCFr1R9vbEFIs8kyvp62sjmy@vrOAarXAJGAuiSWsPAajYV5dwyTlMpzDF29CCGUXHZmIpqVzrKKDOq8oyxMcQfVfUK13bEcleAtVHR3hDv7uUgTxTEwGgrV8ZVEEXWN0oyZCGbVVIpZEzISuD76kW4VBt9YoYpI380Vlb51d96qZjS8NRW0@006fpT9ioecrJzQnqBBy1JyUK4H5pG/35ZOsIxJvYIJF7ZLeAyXGXGSBpxfVqMT0jq6xuSVBPjqqf8PsaKsH76cEeDoZawoeo@bQ/FW9fTdpDtTflwtXKh0xH0dtpDC3c5m6HbDld/oO2OYEiNMnLoEapg0oQSHO3oYeVCbeLKydeOTo@OvlQv42APYYzJM4LHxCqkDgQVLqCiQ7vNjGoNTAYKk5RLQEHqnNDRrNWqzWrf6g@CMZQ5jPc572cngPZ9Xpjo@BpFv8AjncKjWc1dTsI/GfbZfR6Izn2G0ZrV@4DfXMVBvcEWWpfZKDGSam3Ugni/ev9iWEaB9LJiVS3Pcz05gYdlt5zq0PGNjvXU8vCc5v7BMuswC09Emt1Xx7sYcgcl60u15jFnKh@KodZaqWmnmBVRp3wtwsgFnTTAxb5LGKAoL1OVN2DzlpnS1u6nttYqbeU@a6bAJfeq86rD8qy4VqGrdhSEBByBMIcYMVLV2ucAmMM9LZchI4IkTgEmJrQMNWK3ycdIDezLykm1jqHf4WtTleWGqtbfNaRaRaoBg6mME0bVH7b4Hdq5lp7PFSsjcNPX1ypd1qq2Xo4qXnUAo3FW6UG1iykIfnzCwK30gCSA8/ad8uGXvslSm2qhyh0rBOxdD4SJptasjiY1tFqt59eKmXxxDWcsiqvw0zP51TzuDs7kcxuZvA4yBcgaEB9@62Bfgx@EAZEjr@O8htJTZMbkTG6U0/SMbukZJffKbr9KZU5xYgmkQkJaKhO4uw5QDjggAQHZkhW@RiqdX@kpbZcZmyrRMDC9ChXUyHTZwM50Ecwzy@jx4CmVra4ovWUFwywfDQe79Ua5DGLm19BLUd9sFdPrufTbVKqiLLFU1bfeEJaRPxIWBktA0WK6hvnDfj23BOWGNqheQm0Hy/p6vlwfLtdVHQqYe3eyKdfkBlTXJZPgL76aDGJXBdxCPsgFtYmoNXEboIDds6Bq9Y18RQSRBoIxK7JyLIenfZRkcj2fTKaSFZzFXAJ3wdiJBSehV0je1bdkEPXksryRl4GnT/j5lSzweb6iLiUuJRzhsrUNKXEhXV5cbsY3Pn7OxmMDBG/x3GXsJL0ssSzt9tGaCbZEJlWr0XTzdnX75Nl2RYTe3pESZdqlO9lDyY6FvgamZpc@do9RerP2kn@PccceJCuRqqw6a9CWAcsmJcNf4PG1LZaEchlev57Przbq@XXo04ERh0HzeSi6fyFxhPOdadnNdI1ljyVZJhbEdzCUCileCvY@QY2e7VyE0xtluuyBKUaZN/J6I/X@id27KK2qfByuJN4vp7NMo82fzez7BHSSlwm@azx/Zdc45CXcBfz5q3wBqstxQwcYiAfA9qGrLRRkmo99xdjgcOPl@svSy8fPD54f7OHEZllPbuK47d2SW9DvLeVy5VK5VGEV9t757GtskFxdS0JJjquJUXVNHPDQazVV38yzLaBaVgZu39GLau5djZNgjTyKefD58Es/XBttlsCeB4G5DCgspPO1mr6STyUGH776fTzge7H7xfYjlkR1K3/3J7@dX/@7P/lXtP0jeVnxaV5wPQEh0agX1xMXF4OLi0t4uF8h0UjwPK2tp8DMt@boiVo2ITbP6Ot6KuGrwqqvFxL@OxEln8PjAeC7c8Ad5GIB2kBi95ldyOv3NhHleoRyFv1tWv5GQkqUHr96xxhYzFr75MTOkymbZeX36ib@M5yhfq8usVfVGi6EsQ3wjKZJV2q12go5J2tpPL@eL4Bn/bLSSDOaZ7Wsl5a14qwcT81EHzvgZPkr@EfeZF/xfbCGNmvltQ@ZZIUajLpXstnscerDL/16Pl/8uz/51XfNd80vgSdvbGwU9XziZ5Cla86XhqM2mvjBk6JoiEZ7bMHtwJopSwm8MrrDePhw7IejPdSuwHVToU06c22hgKgJ6DNA1FYo2AqeksuQ0E1H6lMVSYokUxKqvRMzQzDYCipEh4YkXUh30Av6M1YFFibdmYAChz4qtTKbfm/oDUg@VCie3siwuxAFUriDalCW6HSf4IOqXmHZlatReZa5RiSSQFjf8n3UgwZ8WroDUR4BDdP1bGxg4AlRDGk7wHg1DEL5JI92HdJuQNo9HqFJrgqVngfIMJ47HskBoVu6g8fdSCqHbprZmxCgwlLSHUAAlEERgO0G22SrKXZhp9OVieK0S9zaiFozjPD8mYTREFobD12GkSsYzubKUYYeKgxjooZNK@4YAuEw@DJaFcYLGJ1sKObQEdNbgwJYpGpAoaKxu3cnuapW7XaKUYkQPmqNQ2VvEy1XVxIAYOFg65N2Wc4wJ53Gyr4zTXaA8TRlF6hOJcMkUAcPAqL1UpLg/9ZEixQ5U1XkUcECiPrircIElEFkRDuvQxP13un59RSLMm9C3k3KFCnQiUaQx6NPNNJjZfIsXko/S4TKg4G/HMXHOYJuZw8gMuilhqjWFbUrcGYgjhbyW6iQT@0HYewoFhTF7lHoju3BiIEW/0JVPMqqnsJonciF8kFcOb/GcLdhIYUfioWhUWGLgcpPRDpLNLdNWuP8geuQthQ6eY57MkmHnS9x3TA820Pn3CC9ZzwV2sIYyxFXJoeUT7rOHK7QzedxcaGRXzsgcJNh1olGaoHyG0zh6glxKtKJwKUoEmUYxokG4rjVs/qQpUPLYqixwy9nsycgYQxbpKLjsQ101d2zobdw/Ky4Fy97bp/a2SNUSaq6HRBbxZHQBAoldqQtS@jBIGV3PfvU4sNXZepMr8/yxQyIhRnA7OQHiC1jB4/ndnPgneGh4LcOn3VuLGVicZeUcerqd1VfUppYo@@43ikP7747M5wYful5J4lBpz/2wwP7dIIU7FrEcqFl8lN6STymFx0nlYRmgSqdetdwxnyggGwVnjNFI0ii1hmEUHUJ@xhgmmZ4ABZbMZT2DnUA1PagZaFGm8Ar48nwKup6U0xoeoLBO@wTtpqXSPMf6UoQqg0ABlZ9dRo6@EFULIcftKFiND7zAHwFWme/DX4JVPDEyQ/jh9SNZtLuNCFvtiTAYadDaVUZbxahpRCzYOvguvqg6EvgWYQczsnJkiKnAWxaTskcdBR/Njqndol4SZldhZRhCEGgGqCgqHDf8Ln2UKGO5vz8XCONSEPP1iwfVVX7eKdndnBigwzqZgOrPxAXDtl475y4U3NiUrmCerz9dWtEl65u3B3zryR18Iz2m6HtWUqy4yexDzxDrconfVI3gYogfKKbPZsUtpsKrTP7gszyjcxFSGZlJDO1lLxEIIwhmFFmnDEzACzTMk8znfN2RXjw68oBOFSWFTqiskIvtPT90GQPOlEIN6Dd0aG91Ts13Z6LoofMJ1gnSfMShiHHoVXYB/YIIjnWOdv2PGOskH8KQyOdKmOSbtgYenfyASP0JuyC6/SyR/VxYyr6KIoOfVe0zuqhsgnp4nqgXJUa@o@4/wj8R9x/NEk0TLY@anDJC50usThI3Kg7KgyJYMZhmEuuCW7iQ5BBRGY6B4Ehx1Nul/AzqxQ7xDe3QT1WQ8IAmiAFjApqfqwfNxzfOl9ppLMnQNMyIQJqHEDXG4TT83ZkRuz3znoD159yclC1EnQ@It/oZHYFNXBawTJGFUSEwfFlowaek77G51h4vy8KDBBQ3AJPlAC2A8VOVSLNt@QJhFOXJzjmGauLzDRIyBJewg2kIo56jtg4oEYMELpHRYJsgg8LW464fkAwgRce3gEdhlXpOgFS4ZtsJAGTM02Fs5QKVVIsV6oaZhPQjlJpdbYooT9URX3GK1bMS1H/8ewvfXT2O9Au5ueeCJb3CxUp3lSsESostURzIayyWjVWr5CD7IrRszzooHa5GCo6ZUhmJRuOJng6WASuaFeJVb6Z4vVDB09kRy5HpDCuVqGI4ypvlrxdhCjlCI@i@SLaOCQEEZ8zEICRmxvNEtFG8WijapUzDjZaEO08lskRZXLEo/DQowWZbIhoMEiKVLli9TRQgx8IVDLA03lvidpqZeYbZ6iSmL1GjTsweArTnPAcogJBQyhJI52Zjbmp12OZjjGtGQBIiFcAtPmNR2VpluHpamSLeBRHZcijuE2QAecVQGDEgitcq5oSERkNdUGul9PUD0DbldN1SdZxExj95fhPzoSO4U@/6pibDqlPO@YyM3//II4NxGysgcaEDD23hgwZByzbpGQGxJJzlylzhGdwz4a3ZWdbPbeV7Ru4uSLrxe7QToXjAVIjeW/gBkbgrq2V@SDIJvp6LoKz2J0jfAxgnzguDDXiWhttrmXSSaIyTdM9cWzfyuCt3VwEt2gXAFenLsXlXmF0fUkSU4B8WIqgOQGh6Nps4j1tzabiW71OqhypREWrhnSYTEo4ngVTLD7wIQH0YKC4rdeWGaRuhokqTUW0I9s8VQ4GwjMJiWwzYFYmyPPg2wVRhfnuZCRIugZRNG4FCl0q03X77gmId6hHFGPPgN@fwMYMGYMB5SXDDByilmOKX6k5KGbGSImon390VPZ5XjFSUfz8NIApZGSYN4tjxKw3J7nmwuR4tDC9w4/P72E8v4fX55dG1bN55kPtKvf8uKRXlQkECDjJxurN2cgItd1XsjOVlcgZBSge4dZZbNPmpTbmdBuCbovgWgfoIxPZfFImJDL@xSL8X1@BYfTd21afgddWHo6B3/Rxj5xC1yn44fKgAsH3U8h7riYXkfaDW6YFYfFOkD2UFUBeJcbloKYqaJgDGEb7crQyIgDfQPO4PekK3dOepSr3nJMn7yzDTvOLq@hBs231jLHVVkTITAxuWOJnMDIjfnW7giOjI6bn8kGdAp1UKq7mGpHOA5UXkIyROYspOb8ShgexI@qhmW/K4f5i/KH/FdaMU3ZVPvsMAn8ymSB9@HR9wWA8GHMNnz1SFBzyUd7/8JrE47c3IwTwIHY2ZCbJpq5jn8@UqEi36BGisNp0kUmXV9htuf3B1Tr8OBTdXFKo3FikaljLUzrIF9W4fV2Nx6gipEm@1HM7kryJ6G5NczFS48AmLGzn47qQK5BxR4NpKnGI3OXaGnOdKzwB3WjezVnQqzTnMNQoJnG6wKZxNckXKQmHwPvwxQmkL@CLAE@soMkJKiwbzlGJ62kY@fSNQUxqES4gjQOUGBbDmyYoG7FQUmiG4BeXUZrmwjTNK2maU2lGLWA6yVggyZxKUtQCVs91VdCzOsEC7oxeOEiGz3VsGx7HNTyclrhI2smynWHJs2QZGHLSSpZ3FWDKyXay/IAMfrJ8SIbTZPlzMEzaVvJdshw2CwzggZUM99BdsHC0m8nyjpK6lAK8DCRMV0uWozqFMFvcShgBVGC5QWrEJTPHFcUMPAs6NhIqMwwpxs/gOIkmXDL0y8E/1/rPb6cBT5yzXKHALM30qU4j1mPwdKDbCPXBzmnJZdGb7x7s0Y6gybUK4J@GwVw8DoEHMTyRnGZGPGPoSysU8IUMIt8sz88R06fv3rhFdkTqQKFUydPpE/Y0kgfaCvnXIXAjNX2lg4gf1tc0CF6Bt8snRl6UzyvZCZOjHOEaa2pOthCpr5LXFArreua@El778RqiuevpQHiraxiE1xKBjfF0kOFosQ0TG7iDaSIhX9znZ8fj0Owbb5RIvTPRiCuIlrnAm5xFyZAxxBt/6rrixOJh1qZYEHrWcw3eyqJ@gXgxek14XUxS5Y0PshDjOdDCLfPUQrJ9IIwUjrObDPUVi7qhMC5PkjjXNJuEyBrqERkaAU89GrzuonaRjxu@hjFHOKmiIIBYzCgVzl/dj5DfXS6/hwJ1iISZBOYJ1vO70qvi9bW97EzOe5Nkr1YgembYg9Rc4ShKYYJyGB3EJPPraO2KiI9bOLiQzxONoM9I@yHaojHBDXibHVtwWCgleGfTjqd5cDzNL0bUVYmkd6aFQouGKQk4vOBRTidFuz6vvODzqhh9aCLb6H10BXvTFRyvPIRHBfBmUM5bOR7bxLWtSdsmZbvogixVLzPOyGn5M6rmiSOwe1qKjZZhweGg@ezBwZNHX4dOd319PSX66PEkf9hqcVI16sc5ZNqNHPUHc4Yt@Qwqm8fFa7qFGG9IXjp25Cu8hDNrEAbwkp2Q/EQbTwleFuPnM20X4vGwMYwKWKeTZmBMcSUUdQzssm2B1wAQYgXKiiGAhOIt4DtDo7UUzskCdeB9fc0mdV/NJm5GajZFL4ZVE65wp36WWMoOfY8um@WqsM8lic5fswcH7MXD7SN29HCX7T3f@Zx9/eA5e7H95AjPKz99fv/R/g6D3@6Tw102mVHAB68HwQEl4PWBZVr9Fl5Km8utMYK84w7GnO8oOynufmj02UPXtHA9atM3@ve63KI5VlDjsXZhODrGOUybbqDp20HAr9YzARwJN206tobb@hmEbcGYto9j3r7btjs2hJVw7DuwLT88WMV6NtQg8NvwxGSGC0l4VQltBaJr6uiGQbyiDsLjIg2AMfzJlYi2zyNYbY0JxEXPR2PwaPfZ40O2/eQB2zl48mD/aP/gySHbO3gG1qdf33/yKeBz//Do2f795@hFAR8fPNjf29/ZJgeegZzG8EQ63Tl4XRY0DE5YMU9xiZsunY5s8VlnCAYSPDs36ACfz5JDB7mPbfTst1Y7WZHwEiN@aJDWBFh0hSCz3uBSZrjmS/sJ5Oc@XcOznGOblBo0lhq0t4portDtoUJ0XHjojxlex2RV6HS4QubJNU@0KadtW0zewT0nOPfND5FTWw5BQ0JLABtBhRtQqoxuF0gmM5sEsgapmT0XNanx1PimQGHBqPfCrSMViTAm9r4gUNzrv@/gfJBeiRyA7sEhL5INPB6ArUYOPABb4w4oiu7jXhBWECGGwcEQ2TMrcofX/cEerf@y9cjhvkGj2JLIE683qlKDTa6wt/uDHt0PwWd56Nonwzdtm6L4FB7vV@j1wrsXWxaQPPBEcVMW7lWDkDIwmw4uNYhtbM6QGjb4AjXgvh@jE/hMqaY0doSbfSzH5hdvnPQMh29pmmzFIdpjJdQiUhWbsu3oRgs6PTFwiQDxlpnpfETxHgip0LptPIh5/0qKhtjzSLcihVvKbsrA/SsZ@HnAACB1aqRjUk9FRzgRjNsRpKz4LlAkztu@j4cHcm4PTWsqQngz5mv77duUQHJmapwU7juk3EEV4SWiGb5m2XE9aOPEVvt4FgW5oNl1B4HN61CZLsHkXjMIjR0bpPaqWptKje4ynUnRcZ1Yoi2g4gWptoAob5MqUTxfJI/YV9jWo4vVaB8dZsdo4QXKk7WzDC4inVs4/QKCML8UEnsbuuJXyJ/ShHe8p4s6S9Xag/vH6vtXGbwWgrMFfhVauImQX@zZx7SgedA6H21A9FDuEi0tvFvEH7YwtthTJ7gltvIQGIwDuzaM6@41K5Ef3z581R0Pmcy6k@O7d1UeS0XOxDny0O8qE@6WYfUwyQzFaTCx1yPGOyGzwOuV0CVDMCN@fQ/Pk2AtVAAjDvIRupJ3@k4PwULC0rWGHeAs4tYuUd0R/BSr0daJUJCkR4nXR/alcr@arqWyk50jLIZOJWTRmRAyXuo12X9C/dUVcA@uBwf8@/bgStfmjncPHwXtwbXQPipvanoxLN4txWDdHuz7a8Dyzu3nAgtlzywGzDvJq9AiSo@IM7OciHbHXp/iqyt1R20PwGDfizMoEdBYakOHlqhDdacKj5CKg5kIRIdHD3afPWMyH59AXOB7OGRoCzaIsJf4lSd896ztELPTIqEpGixHwlPoMrV1LXyua8xzkbeAVQgZJCPwETGL6QtGieuJnoVECNpNTwwxxNx07i5CHuTXBeBL1G8LzCsxEcOiAkpzi5ngnY/txzd1C7xluGwc35NPO6Z5341XhXnjOKD45h/jBE@KzK@/F1w@LofpcAHLejOkArdBksbbcjV2CAkPIKCmTdfgNdUSVilumucCdiLEHe7wyk1L2L84QREhcSGcy8Ixti6EY5E1Lh8vh2IO7TzEbsDALZ3Ck@9QBo@QxZPLZrxCU5NOT5nugkDIxEus7sWpAqI3LivRvbfKpJ@sRgJ5vK0tU27qYS4bODsrYFcWB/oE9zYXZ9nDbFLAba9NSv37SYr3ElMphTifW5jQEyAXC4XVm2DPliKMrv6isHkfMss/g/4AxvcTkP7Yp@l9oNz9J5nQf0IA16COb5UPG8xMRBB15vQpU2WnziieP8gLnxeCzKDuYLOLV3ZNp5pio5m8zYfOe6Q4dApypQyxJhwVlLeaK9i/vD45ZMg3prf08enxxoaBcI/g5c@iw3UxXSoxJzwzOu1meZ5DwfixpL6Lx8foNNK1Z@bo0Bzf0MoLg560zBYvQEccMuLbajPhFAMlQrOKGl7xh5N6ldlZPVWvxEu4t/9ol62Q7rnO1BSk7MmpGMtZsp3rMkCsl6YjsNego3if@GX4QR4yIUhAEx3KUwg3qRvzRhgBYblONzOIbZ@Cpeqzld7xTcNBxR4ZmW7HvgsRafJ192AvNW9CPVeZig@Z8weOArEysqrJFBXccB4XIU2D4LWJ7rF@SsKrCcQGyWsuBDayeilX3JCodE4myPTrG43MilmVGfS5htP3h955@/TE7Z51WI8NXrdG5vjtG8YKa2wVdUbe5Sov9WIVj2MrDLWGlNhGjghWZHCLlIoey4xppCgR15PZZPhdWWIpMtBYuYwnIGaolK30QyrEk3JBtV8vNqpONVfp151GBc/qBelqkNbTCjrchc4TWAtfkK8HDexKfxafbbWcM@YNW2MYJUVnPxid/cD@HWe4xJ5tmi@nbcbSHdyshmdINMc6V6LLzpEyJZR/pDt0iEfHo980XYyzLW0bcgDYz4Cw6o/oPU5Jd3LacBC45CMSUpGE2Dv7nXQnPHWUowkDCFK3G2F2NgnOJIyC6z7cdcx3Q6s6l8Z0POqYioGoY0zidvKxLOMRQMyoOHpVb0i@ZhlmFzOB11q@o2hsc5Pfd38J3jRJhzs1DI8OPuQaaMT1DfgMaDEBkyDB3KfjGxIUH@06GrgLTUEFdN6FNrpLJAiiD27jZhd0HInibwICOOLvcJFKEzOYQrACOZEf9aO5A1QoNz2ux1UEPAXJK@UOFhZh8/SqE@C045twhMkKNIH7nXNEJ8cVPKIEqk62K8WIwqd4cEIJLUMLm4@4pColrxp@epNoSiyaGkYLA8dQcedGbOBEFox@HlvQfMZsx@r1INMcF3cm6EAjHccV6aej9P06ptmIMs/91Sv@6pS/xv15piahNOi/J4HK8UBy4mIS7pLJk2CZK2lVGckmGtS0qYHEMQlbuS6srwVu054ErkVVyaky8tic8lBjPi/n1D73WZqKExF45F/n/oK@86Lmo1xOhb03nT5@JVFBFu2NFVtJZqhUc@zeFu@cIh8kMxmwyRiPjvVNZMcbpTgyKdgJCGg4jU/NtladQEnrIcehNiPXNu/JmhAmtpTZbPBDh1ca1pw2EsMSpZkmxI3ofCGkQ95LMRAEEwmNhS23FkYei8jjGFgMtRQmyw8tXmngULTZJl7FY4zv8BU29unMheES8z3v8JyPeOH5YeRpBBHTXZLno2mam@CxD@4oCnVNLzJJezwLcT6TeBKb5I3StPiR6Q7Oci9FfCLOKEJOcQXvkY/A9CSAHpLvoipEz0vpZ9kV6VMDROhBzxqxbRxFGHSaSpo6j446Vn1UfkRqWPzhYNDDRUUS7M7pxLNQ3JEv4GrKBGJsGU2T9nHjDg@fQZM4Pw6RNHaAkM9x/8fEwx@e4GXbuG6DOo@AteKEih1o0rYz5vMV0GZW8/xUuMWGPl8UhcH8STwTvOZ460FM@wPDtDQJZDEfpByJF7XD27eYLsdjIah@C7q0siR9bWibpzuf4nLtup5b1WMoOxOrvTltdW1yUAqQFHrkcyCuFvQ1SYot/Zp86VdFgBn2CDv6L4A2rTO80lnahh6DAvognPqWd2a1NUl6ZkVrvAgXSRkXHvHYtDv0TD53A7IVXgWNp339DF/tAgrDL/bPfDXYpKWwjIRrUpPFZKjqM7uNCAwPlHRcXPyl9Qg81c/xgZH6VgBIWUmx6SzR0rLIC8kufZxnAmygWpLY0kOEBscNbBNqhiaqpB6A4qsck8T4xfWxnEB6Zs/AQ77avAzg6ZcJBsIMhCtF1@VBEmviH5UHJgoWLqEbYc1kgfu51FaguVueDdx3gmCqFYoWyztU8NHD/7e9Z9tOI0ny2XxFurBFlcRdd6NSN5JQm17J8gjky0oaVECB6EbAUIUFdmvP2X3YH9gP2E/Zh/2U/ZDduGRmZSFkqS873TNn@py2iqq8REZGRkZERkRWa6J2clh/Xz6tCHh@e3ryrnpQORB7H@kIG8/BKemreH1yBNxFH5bzofgJvLDKNahp0YdE@c1HUfnw9rRSq4mTU1E9fntUhdag@dPym3q1UkuL6pv9o7MDOlyHFsSbk7o4qh5X61CsfpKmXlW1RFRPnByK48rp/mv4Wd6rHlXrH6nHw2r9DXaGh/Zl8bZ8Wq/unx2VT8Xbs9O3J7WKwIElDqq1/aNy9bhykIX@oU9ReVd5Uxe11@Wjo7mBnrx/UzkV5ANgjHKvAlCW90BVxZ5onAfV08p@HQcUPe0D8gDAo7Sova3sV/Gh8qECwymffkzLRmuVP51BIfgoDsrH5e9gcAn7EazAvOyfnVaOEWjARO1sr1av1s/qFfHdyckB4bpWOX1X3a/USiJxdFIjhJ3VKmmB109R19AGYAu@w/PeWa1KeKu@qcOecfYW3RkcmOT3gBiAsgxVDwjB6OWAowUknZx@xFYRDzQBafH@dQXenyJOCVtlxAI6TOzXzWLQISCxbg5TvKl8d1T9rvJmv4KfT7CZ99VaxYEJq9awQBX9LT4C6UCnZzRqnCeAix@BWBOKctM0naJ6KMoH76oIuSwNFFCrSmohtO2/ljiHtZxLGMaS3hBtA96NaUDp3H/1ycdkjfctL4ttMTrB0f7JQQV2ZJk@yoo@nMGuszWX@cj8BjuN/gg/Yxlm2n5z0m30Bp0hxorqamzguAm6abxdwwH1XFwkvnLBirSjUIVkstF4V26AoltrNJz0U2rGwHishrRyf62UI8eIud9R80YDz6tXjPedGKJ2l@Q5Jvnh4fkClmTsL7Fnm3fjOyKXa/uyGgbhY8PKRBTwqcg1npQAa6RYRrxXIuqSLBD0uyfJgSraqvlsq4FmUHR8pELDAP4Z/BT94M3BeAHcmc1auRwqsQRG77OvuuFOKLUB/SMzC/Q61GU28P0fu3be7A51/mx3OGzbjqPqUNkQ9MCu7TxSvel356pn5usTsHSqLFPGB0rvJhFGHy9LlAk5L9kxjczGfxoh/XEUNJy7AY2i1BXZoqVx0l7i6uhwlBYyRQVGT9Ako8x3XP5QfY/aXL64Vpp7/1q/57WF7oCYbhY2vHOqd0l/Xl9yAVhglFMDUNKTmS5yOaOOcifRhW@h4DUWopz6tFdf@7SvA0pAkJ14fbNP3I3HvakJPfDh707Lx3tnh4fAOhHata31zY1SQmfJ@pDmvx@xH0qCSknCRrCPg5xGn4xVsg@CD60UI3N2RP5EwLkcFsTc5GrS6CXma9BuGXFHJWRkONwAL1kZoAee5SMeLEGJNJ4nFL0uXJmSAOzYUB0czY03JRHfA1mJaED6qvRnNGtT/Afb1stfLXE9IElAksQo9SxQLmgXxPesQ@UJSsoN5dnBIllL0TFnXdM4IFMXucdi8Cz9krRtzGLAnoq4XmnaqSYA8XweCqHcJga8st9SvhBp6KVkX/Dmg6Q3ePwo89FRdjovCMthDdB4qGuiPToyOstBn8uWL3ddmKKlJd3TjkBrviOBorUnzcY6wYexGgiUS/QZdMVcwyWdD2S@S3Jw/TbliC9MqZiEA9spSYqVv4FyFw1HtlJSeUDkb5VdQnBbOlkJY@1W95FQRT7qfBQKnTE0/Sp8UPu/I04WtL8DGie0HmHLyNn3JExSq4wrUF8JKb1bdaBgnGJE2DRffYyauTMn5loPTJ7STDl8BlAgZ2emXnykLIUdewECkMjRsGGuX@1xdu2B6vSt5cjqeB4yaN2MbCH3CrVV3Gs3s3GZJrErrc5Q8IcjHLY1GR0eQVXxLStuTVr1oDLNqfLiZWBxc47K45FbJgOIXvBEpdfslDpPWXm5yhQfkCmTjA2nrTMfgVh69@Dp3LIwMlrGeL884VKIgqZ3EZ7746RU5UPB3rfxBImcGr1OSeswWzaqybj5yAxzTfKz7PvYzss2GUPw8tjwFjeIPrdOmfWi1oT9kvxAsJPIqTBKC4js1skCamlbvdXQk2USKVRDfzbgnPM@W7VUiSzn75AQmtHwWXHszQDk/tOGzSSWW64N0@iaiJ2xWULWx4tyW8PhGERHD8cNMKZ7Mycr3kujgz8IJmOZbhD2s95YWiSU0A/doNjE2jttM5zenEALeiEGI7SzRB80pBsfHUA5@8g0syFsIF5Fo7vK6NibrhSEvRN92QGcUBZRQuKO2BA//cSlGKEyw6dPGOwFWrkgl0zqB88d9PK7HY5/xL0fRaBB22/rRKJGk2QL5EmqDiglYyvkoY@GAVk0YCrQAqIxUWBDmvZDhT16U5KTdFuyomSWmGqURvLz@9FEqpyhoKOIcGXvQHwbGZhMxFJRZvLUuT0LxXUCZZHCdfegMkbJPePH08K6GGiW8oqFCPelEh3xifmmfvqIT9LI774McPXAGzzLliIoAowyK56f3udzBB8m5nvf88dt0yYKkkzbG6H5jVSf4YBoUZkOZfq@lhcG/gw0gFauN81RGw37@@H1oLE/7Hvd3rDngZ6Gec6nzPHwcUaPOGHd8fA2oOtx6EPbKNSeRc@cPobTqeFvfS5ZMlJsBaE/sk13hHA8K19zFgiynKOPn9D7FdH3aD7Xma6zth5VSsTDS8ndruCUHqy7WlhUmU/usQHJ4HbnPCU4RDSkuCMjtrR0r0DzawUMGJsiIzznAYe8GMTbgCI6holBrIC5535gDgI1swchPm9P023KJTjGPEr@gY8XzAQ2vU57eJEqcJFv0CPglShs5Y2qfIoyxXyC@DB7GN3Fzd8ZegDgV4BfWF1ELYsIgVhcRyVTClhfkUlBARby/usRjyZODFys14VdqB9rtDGdbzX@efYQNsjDB4QimS7vHlXiirRB8cFr1ewGsJzGzMFNJSVSDqXlQBGkHNr5hwnWf8w9lhY/HuKy5QwZ075s2TaAfghVLcASXpE55z1rgswpkB9fMcXiU2dtDoHuIo8y4xoH21KSCwWY9Hh/xWOt4RiYsTWHPenqkQrC4Sj1ROw9yDsWZlhbhOuW4zzq58vE5sJmudwm1LozfJyVEvPwzBFNHGPkUQY0hOorPWsyn0fi1G3genMbs0fw8BDOIv8ovano@W7z2sdN8RM67KqNRi8pgh2TjZb0@/MGDLzxMAeRbbJ61SCO0UCW0Zjxo9HUHJo0lp6OIaI@CfscPtqAOey3Dbgz5@dBpM47w6nUpepTLFkl4hPzrGNMJvClUQedLzALHEu4mklpgXOantFRXiHTxGTB@IEbRKnYz0R2KLbgRpM1R0eUzL9jN9BbqICcCJ52TQ8HnaNfI4yS6EvjjvR4aMwyhcsStzTVLYFWQaW@1pIKJ4ef540ptXIPFbDEF6BCj@geb7p@@qh@7VigHLTAtemzdOTNp3EwjlgBaOAf81NjijJw1JWsGVtR8YXQINYAawG0lG7fZ3UVpb/emCkevRvkMgIFgl/b@GdF1sDs2xt5jW2sMm3PsIgj0c2rzRGZXa4SERT/RvTLpciiLimu0IDPEEN9twAtYHpSgh4PBSizjkl5MUDlHEFFt4DLEl5SdtPIn3PBd0SqLLC2bpTILyqxbbaRWdgICBaLy0SAgMyyuEjUCmx0C2ExSmwuHk9UAgRiRfuMcZgKOStxHOqZYwTCI0GrOcp5QaTzkoLp49q6E/uo6Zu@bueNr/n5r4AfDeF5pjD/dSsf@xrrtliMV43VBHw4Zq@xj4AKxwRYc4Vf9x9Fnpipy7VPqKFkxKQM6Yc9QFXqFvW27A@B2KGYayVjqPbMwG@lfjX4RpRYcvWvJ1IXMk1/6dcPVjmmKkBkZn/KOqdCWWzWB0lgtXCnx1Ghoqvy6On0A0qlHXbEu/rhYSypa3Om/Ixu/PF6Pp9HGm6aOeyVCzVaknrDXLx0rjPp93Oj2@/H75o5Yv14EX0/GL5SCrQPMwJrIsgOx12@xwFhgKJYOiPDVFHVn3Q65oUJeECJcwezxiVlrgNB@09P@7y8q5P9h5qU@@sVDhDHdyX04rv1WM6UrahTKKiNHsGfLHV4BujBFx10w9YHVdQY8mXlzATbluPufsENBO8hocmiLMTOl8g72Xrt9/vDtHg/HPfbmAfg2d18hcNDs0Kei@ABI8XuTgLKNpsW/qde34gaxiImqWNzal9St0Ko9O6Y4v7U71amI9s6/7MFuwoMeQWHuYJpptPC6lqOzPn@hGaZDgHsJ5W@8UZ2i/A0Xxh2ermAoyeAaLWQXqj6xIo4ZBKTOHu8NCJ1MbhZSsUAQ3dIFFAp6Wl6aSQPFNfItS6mhQ7iMM9tSJgwo8rTamAg2e/HFT@Fnc7TmCJl8@eJ/aszRDoCoBUolx/gE5Nh/1MGlvXhXLoQlm/wzo37fAcrNLBCIvGy5f7l1i6Xy@LFaGVFlMt78JDJiPJeWRzgi709cQC/9/D3kltcXy8xzz1wvsDLPfXyTuxBG2TgXGldjw/gJ3xzMSoMnbVxil/k3Bfp0ouGu7NbCnLn5T0M2oen//nXf/@ff/uPXFn@@E/8sUc/zv@sC2Wz2dyL1pcXS3cl/H1@cJl60Tx/MbpMdUtIZcjuz8aB1/cM79FsK/FIhFS732s@FDWlvWd6AblqorukDf@4LmhgP/3ETxdh9DiOHjEnalTd64@uPaouqIVdN1VOLS3B046b@ucU2U7ke0@//wzvhYO8nJImEGrx3h9Rru1Xq2baceT6JL13fMyRgxdYynw58uDqKqmu@cuci2xWXGbElQYP3TwaXDAOIquZDMy/SCDV6Mgnh86updqAh9Jk@mZzPB9M3QRdku@U6ZwvP/OkpvKy/YrP0KiNFWB4WL7Evuoy7hWHD@DisZebOS9srF9mkslkQl@I1mgRm6PeRtSXviBLHaFTfgYOwxrBkoGx0wV1LuICGkRkJJN0XdZSi691sweoWpPGxAp3MmXI82hvooEkNJtjCzcnU0AZCxU@uoJMBBOKwkDZYPbUMzwAgMLrdohxCb4BORj5rV5npl0e8EaKqHfYKzFkbll07kXMCWvctOS4nneiBgEhKAVQrh5sdL5BRt4QyvaI2/EY1W8QN@4T1ZVM/i3WaIK1Q9Bo2J91@9CZTa5UwS1wJ8C8IyerP1ChdNgD12z6IPX4ckXzhEW@vAh300dTxKCFJ2R4P1Qfc3KxwMfHv5SNEtYDSjjyfrgOhoLY/QE7EA078AgbPkbR8REWkeEKbqmSoFCpReVY3S8n@cDyyHHEiEsiVuF3dPhO5EEmSNKH5UV3Mk0In8aMHFkT3@5IShvh1X6oSMvcoI5cSRatFX36BlLlDZ5V4jklIAVLZukuMWANM3HVH1zp8fPpZoDXEWYt1SV3U2T/BOBYuhsVLk/dcSyAxcZVunkMTzjlJdjDIOg1AVkwRDlNlAKRgwfG0OpFKsGdSWrB40BEML5aHukVZY5PkZI/HVF8PsP7DE27A0UFsYJ4QIpnYj6e3WGOg6FkefBrMBxkiOU2/bDXYgdK7v254sUjPBenY0oC7OGOQHnwcJx6gqmHC5VdSB4X01RH7RCeMFgB1/@1Fr09wpk080oWLQNHACBNHHp2LiIkRS1qSqAG4kiRMJL/t8Tgsxhh9v1uL4zVScsMDOx2zqO4U6jHRX6FAJvYncMsBkqok2bNEq4kvpVrBjJe9Q0Y7ZYjg58X0Z4aDO5qfPGkrslDoni6rfv0ofmRAseEGlYwoA@Xbzo@Q7S54l5HSeQwlWc7TqoimoWv9kCNSxCZXyxTgA81ILnFPE4y54CN4hw2gJ3OLYOIC@djzRsEjMRt7uTEo@bQy9PFIsE95q3oRUGKRHCX0CE9X/6/@41NZXOM8cmw@KAU0gHs0ZHDic6jMd/kwhV46ytBXSbHA9Y4nmBGOnZkkTsKprDp8SI1OtVwzHWlhi5nOEOS0ojyo8DP85Q5l3NV1Xij2pfx2pkUh3R9UYFdtiHpjBwZ7yW/PuPNHHZT1S5HbNHRG/26U6FlMjJLO0yo2ZEop@3V6yB60CGG7ljSk3O3iDSUDq@4vBqzlCxAuIw1Tm3REY0sZ/oELUAS@yqUJ@GwGv72Mj3llpZnffolXbcKcoEHYrAUETwnJ5/gEb2Pnd9KLUA@0ANGwP5rXuDDcyLBkofUMK3joLs3nNr59IV1YaULG9uORXqylsOSrQA0o2TL52xpeGWj1D0pKyPZtT/5zMLHzV677Q9ULlaoKnvTnxqy2XM053/R7C7gG24tYuK@ZfDyIAOTSC8krul5NPa6Nx49vhnWx96sCpsQ/TwZ8HzWsL1T2IzwTib6csprtNwGUcO6Qz05ooknDZG8ojyQfFohiQacic8QFxYgwL@HAO5Tjz@ID9ZAgzl@tl1o6Zn2TZjUK5ZQAnaivuKDk6sEX/h7gzfSNvgd0KZt3AgsH@nT3DXVUkbAD8pB2HjLNVjU7@NJjz@InUOo1MGS8PjaaK6VFn0g0LxSub4@lCH7Q19p6IMrqdiErevGzaQf9uTI7g1LjQsrzd99TOqkuq76gfuPyWQ4jztjHNjueQ9WaaTLEKOKsCCVMNWKoT8qdNP4yewYCQ1SVeG0H8U1oo/8Xekrc8PS/a5SNTArh3Fgo5RTHGfCUDegdikR7bNCj/p5TPlAOAApCMbyiC6eJtZ8Z84xzjDmDSFmoif3r6Gz/y0rufyGThsiLCm9VLpnMg@LdH2KKkiLvDzENrRaoBS@eXx440vNVqoThvJq3BrHyTR/d4X1Ec0tJv0ZqFJe26bs8jy20GLCofLXNNCphRjamc1ZoLGawogpSRDLGcnECIxn2dIdR6UvZBuslEBJhnleyFYSkx7pAvYGTdzbPNNajLj3yVHSm5aAqCjQVFsxVbm7RRub9PdFq160gylY4zKlKbKLaAONZNYFSrgmg0cR5d9HVOGXIYrhWoQn/vKboSmOgDiW7hKJReSrWYd0zTLXuo4guseXCHHPtSA818YCQbfZx6SBEWDzzcEEKsl@WwnDy6LcBbYYl4XZMdyL3rHWwwpkMBcyrg1xHIYwGWNS3SRIVwn4HxMcA5e6QYNOzAICImsuoQtRfBhig/CtrREyZYHIJZ2E9BnKJfmaoMJmwaFOntATRuD@CvGe2SAexXTuBb/hhkIix7JoyADCx3c/2useMEvHxrfQJA0cOTJKM3teHo0wqOAxK3UuKVNZ2AKaF474hQZqspUUeQ9CO08umXgGILCkgTn1oDOqvSINvIEPw9AZOdmcG7lhsX6oDN1/JPu3wrHyVZAUoAWEvJIOUD6jK6B5gqWEQIGstEBTL4MUoFrHzizsJRLVSFwk1MYoWe3gBblVLzQI6VmhXToQ0Q2q49CwKi60mioLkUgurCZsTDGK1gw6OvJbaAjXVqrAMezB0uyQg7bljdwAFgdK6iZj7MocztKSkLCRyXpOxlio6McQxXDEkHExkPEWc6QLTAhfEuLllgLLREt9o4X2By4gS0Src2mxIILsNZJDIgtNLsL7ZKAxvxg7VPVr@KFgiOFcvBHhhDiqzv0SQZP4uQidx@cjREoGvb8dKv1ZM/FUUpX3dj9Ei7wXbxZ4Lzb3nlmQQ2sD7j74t9fiOF8KLI32H7FsBl8/4/2XzBTwDxMoxSuEOokAcPsgdORd488ivS4bhA2@Nl2zX9TjpMtduw3bMTBbCmhKg54Ykg@SMPCsHGwpwcDP2jCVks7dS1YIKiaCMq@ZydqRXiZIMTPUX5WVgDDVkWHcz6A5ci@iSE48uhq2OC8AbFD4vUNZAUivLbBahAoRVzzHnzKm8lmH0xR25ErmEYjlhuxWjkHCQ4NgGWtv7IVPErGiIzl22BcDTBIFUtY8HQbZhKj@fJHsKXLZ8pPlsuQy2bSXI/FsOTkC2WL1F7bx15XTIgMttGNpyC1cqGTAJ5UDUAwT1EcP48iYL7mWeeT2y8W@f4gvf9SNYfkPL74sa/S34kLMciTEtBYKMVEBWauFhjeqp8sTe4BlOyANeVmKPdzfMN4frBvV33Bhf3wTu4jKycpD6hZfL@g2vB3KGppQZYdkf1zYEfJaXtNXllzbV8K@v6B5vqNtePUf2/Df9zac07jAbKOP7DTG1P9j7v8e5h7zV/a38lv5xm927qvfWSZhWXPnrUJYz0Vh95vNi@lB/mK6vXbyl2SY3C3m3o/hb5j8S3JjK8mP8AC/VtWvT8nd5A4W27hLznKu68KjbKV8CK3sfq/bxFKzHfhnd121uzFL7mZcqv5TcncDHgrFIkByMa1sX0y38vi/VfojiR/m6YoWPh5qdUQ5beSGwGeB0kWe1PJhEDW5b@wOVSQBpY7HDaS480OjGQIYnWemxa28lFWAgDj5wydf3r@l0mZI@ZHyx4SU0YQjLlTaB@mrx5VgBeguHPhDXdBuL0WvKOGEyjWBUkIEtLh6md3Ao@srmYNCA6DzTZCYya7coF7Y1DGmN8O/u/lvLJ2P4pUVS4IRP9uUu@KW3BX/NylGs/B6OCguyGqfFPswXaEvfggYlmDQG438kCX@rj/wx5TKBIaDgg5es9fCSwn7vR/Z/e@Valy0qKHGD0GDY3O4oexoJqwX38LK6t2QVvQZVqV6xvOxjTX1Cxg3XtiGcTIquqbbC68nTbqQoD6eVcMTykSRw6TmIWelyIEs18zdeOg4QGn8AyAxKAHsYDwZ5OhiNxDYMFYGc@/feD8CaHiZLAyt3YBiaOz/0aabWwN/RCEu007HomuS/H675o@8sccZ69BrfuJ1/Spm4oHJCK4tVJ6S4g0F14RmamKtLBHGQQ6X92FlOHsY8f4gpcI/CbVCYLgxXddjYZy6ZELEu60sRU1ALYtDC@iK8M5wGEblOWpcV6Cf8RqUjw0miUND8HAwGhFwcxz/igJiRQj5guCIfspOoxfUEUEzFj28RgNH5Q8mN0Q7@lrb88KrS5mzzi0Y14uTx@vWK3mlvGUhQnGapLG5sIVfJux7SeeSCZk6QI8DBGuGBAryhEzotPAGNIUgGDZ/oERLyJVgQSL9ZdU3uezJjR4e0dg98Lse8YrbJibjgbftXkAFsGau@xlkd0ZROkaqzUk3yPJaoMCKXhBM/PXNrTUCiHZ8VbQ9bMWKFnPQ8tgbz3IE3HV409ej2A6vRd//5Pel9wqBTel8eVESneGNZt6kT24tGw6RDqAyNlLAgr2d5ncHlcOjcr1ykAYxZR2LBxSWpMvaBnL58wp97/QxUwOTEVbh5ZttbqwxkdtBOvUtWuQY9G9NtK@YAKsGgiCLe0BvZKdcqib9LLhhMUK1fdBN6@NwSjWkskbjckNQJnTVhKWQq1Z@MokhXQH2lUQSjCU2gDo4MBW5Pe4D47lX6EFeARiQ3K0RAkX2kX8i5Vo7zzMZvaZe0VMGGGsms8tGFmu/3wPFM3U6GcS4bYrWjidSwOTw@J9Z2/MU8YWsVRLXLurxpZabL@m4vU/2xPmir6TuIBQ2I64@3Jup@bMnMjLNAoQ45OWsQib/@79STukuSqLTt0MHr14Qn12VOTrLTL3Cd9XaqaAFkxVCtc/Z0J@G@5zp0w1LukJz2J5lKblWex@06rb92exjZDtfYK9eWWm57qrzBbocjzAD6AiYoV@HFp0SvuvE3ukQsdzFxQAvoF7G0L0Px0evYcrRT8wPwvM/Xy6/yKVTKccp4RA8l@L7Dk6O36KVf@xkydp/OB7eSLyMPd1JFmb7JjjPXxL0aQuHlsNVCJyz64dy9MHerO5134C0ZKc8QAG6JVFgHExKb8eT8WUl9E1CmQsvZzFx5FrxybWcL12XSl2P/U6JbRV3gfvJ7jqlEP5cm12sQxdusUith1DJRa@mOaz3BrBbv64fH7mpHU9gq@6CVZFaaWriAEIhgrHxVRmvo4qRDnAVoqqQo/WIYOC/lZS1Gx/LTs7bTZXu7h6E54jz6YLwk4oIuG1P0pLixu79KS2NIyqYjXwXX/DW9l2lbqWhLqZgwZcD3N5mxLQ4iNVVfTC5IaegLXBWwzKuu7a0RO@wyiRw3WI@72BGlDtoLcD746FZXljj0t3Yc9u2RqQ36i24LamYLeY4kCXIFTaK@fXNb4Zj2CJcvJB@KQAW4qLW8qkXzpZANvRddfPSEsjJsJu6z9eWt056e3/6sF3bOLBbze8LVtr6ISC3/fHIBGDs3WZZLAIeO5a5dgkIjFxsebmR9@Mwt9bOt0DyLGy2/c11fyu/utVa91e3m9vb263O2lazvb3pba63mjlM9k5Vsje9AUhJFpM/dtt5WrcPCWZbxfx2p1MobGy217c728X86upac2u9nV9b62wVvNXVjXZxq7nd/LrUFsGTAAar@C7uHfMc@OXDwl3iHm@XtZ3/Aw)

Wenyan-lang seems to ignore all non-Chinese characters outside `「」` (see [string literal](https://wy-lang.org/spec#STRING_LITERAL)).

The code is based on [`console.log(5);` snippet](https://github.com/wenyan-lang/wenyan/wiki/Syntax-Cheatsheet#misc): `吾有一數。曰五。書之。`.
I replaced 5 (`五`) with 281 (`二百八十一`) (see [Chinese numbers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_(Mandarin)/Numbers)) and removed punctuation, which is [optional](https://github.com/wenyan-lang/wenyan#helloworld):

```
吾有一數曰二百八十一書之
```

Placing Wenyan-lang before Aheui breaks Aheui, so it is placed after Aheui (`밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희`).

Interpreter should be called with `--no-outputHanzi` to print `281` instead of `二百八十一`.

*Note 1:* `二百八十一` can be replaced with `「281」`, but it breaks Nial if Wenyan is placed on CJK line. Wenyan code can be anywhere, but I like when Chinese is together with Japanese and Korean.

*Note 2:* there are two other Chinese characters outside of Wenyan code – `退` in Intel 8080 code and `在` on Incident token breaker line. Those chars doesn't seem to affect Wenyan code.

*Note 3:* Perl 6 `｢｣` are different from Wenyan `「」`.

Answer (score 5):

## 282. [posh](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/shells/posh), 13263 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<  
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo     anet/112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu?1&&1Prers 6 4>8370::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>Exps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody/'='d  Float#  +- $2;#8在@,,unction
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print(#~$+/ .---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce`  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @,,:1'<
#  |!o51@!00:8:8; ; ~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~-<~ -<<<~-! `=> #
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  >[};]+ pppppee^ee*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcxtLdiD4rJr9B/uSLPAKAIEqoEACBAECFEWRV@wriWqRurrdIAQVCgWgRKAKqiqQgCgqunt2e91j76ynp8fR7vb4tnvWs/Z6IsY7MTNu79gzEfbrhGOe/APkj40Nx4b7H/SeczKrUAABkOp2R@zDFomq/DyZefLkyZNfJ5u61/3Zz2L4sKdOb9zpOT7zTc9nLdc6N12V3R@ze7rl5XPrkoShdt3OsG/avleSYkxjzDYv2KFtWC1wY75zZtrWW9MFvxxjA9fpuHqf@V3dB4sFsdgDs/eu/85nhtPv63bLg5DrjD3VwbM9NM6Y3vR8Vzd8y7HBa4Ox53ZP7zdbOoMQpjtwTZ/A5xmAMM4ozrRPgbHHjuuZmLxhep6DjpuMbZv9gT@ugqUIIXTXch7tPvl0JvIWY5/qkLNBzxzN5EXLsheW6bZmYmga@/zk4GDWNcc@UxybHVzPn7bOnrue3tNn4W@w3aHvHPqz7nm22zFtneXULTU361lg9139WpRN5pp6q231TNWyDaawrtkbmC5DF9Z2XKgy3@wVs8VsY3cSUzUwbnHiOQO2EjxMdzseeDrnJhhNqImBZbZY23X6TLe9C0hJ28pOwiPYrWlyMCCDQGjstQexWybzbGswMH3uCcU1XfKGlFnPss8kTn1PXac1NCy7A@FMwOtg6FOZPMmAaFU2EDSsooHFCAs8GGTh2Omb0brwgHgh197ANKy2ZXDkmCPftD0or6cyC@ruwur1WMvsQYQJdCPNPIcNvYhTs6d3VUOVELmYCuuf9ZjFjMGAcS8oBmTpIFtkZt95bbG34N/remw06DPP6oO3bzjttmmyt@agC9FZv8WMsSG1HInBYwxmShfaVk0IY5tQwr2nXwPc@YhSuw3Za7FmJBzkhfJNpdZtB1DoMlvvc4owBmPCAIAJY7QdR0X3lmN6dtxnF457xpqmoWPRMTHP7LT1YQ9StNpYJUALlsf6DnyhIm0G2YLIPuIDYWNi0tyCYDJBFZsDaJxYxQ6SDNR3UNMXrg404nqiLn2rDxRi@XGPmbpnIdeCKJ5pt4g6BiE/c6C00Ypn5xY0PkDF0CXYnukS@RNchqUAkHpIr4kL1/KBKrAUu@ypqbvsxDXNJKdV0zP0AVJqNElIzMEUfCyISsS5vR3fPzqIA5HyGKo@AKJ010@@@hVJZ2qFrTbK8KvIclnaf/KAXa6eopnzTSDkgZvQk6zynnmZ01MTfiOtmem4VxJAlQArPZZxBn5GVwaQQcWHDGZ0NKJJOc@pg14kYbY9UweRpsNDtaA2gBGwz9NUMmPousjhJ0jVz6DQPcfuAD6hsO7Q5lVeyEIVAP21vDQzz02kAV5HzgVh@KQLFAL/EDTCXXinQwiFbgeao8BokK7n9IYUDmJ6PrZJwApERYiHbfY5a@tWD6OAP4LiuXZND4gT4wztFtZ837LNlsqCbBDncaE9nkNyOgAlB2gN/Qh/oUxBYKgIh4qKXh9@/YetTgfg7BqG47YEuX4OxG5Q96hTZqGDY0iwjq33KFsQLo2p8@iQwLnes1rE6XR7LJKgTFCqF86w12LUUC8saHJdHRiuCUzC8E1O5M7QhzymWV8/41zR4pQLBe/rTahYSoDSpmIr7N4e1JIBzZxoRukP/XaRKYN9FvcyLxM7pcTOyqkJmUuqybXVTKZTBoJT18gJbPFllPP57lR38TnrAKEMB1i@VhqIgNnOhSAcTVlHMiHOA@iy3On2ao5MY@ibWLvA8ptUkr4@psgR9pInGMB6Tg6PsIqgHt2eo7dEHb9AOvEugLF2WVMHZu4j00Y8RXOK8SFvXeQttgedmPlmCFkCngQ4Gvtdx84xxWCyUXEgQCI@Vfx4Ou4240kVO5pEsmxVDLVt2a1EfBuaURVwFk@WjYpRs0r18kz0aB4AzAWCQU5jJoykjK3vxHKQD/UGXRQiIKjtDYCJulhSQwdy8LCn8kFOS7MmESp1b8AqiMldmHHAU1P3QsKgNsbbEMZXkPMJCJM2Md00zVakZUKrBgT73jX22nOwy6c8YYUCL7AxUb0DYh1E5gXZ5QXhKZHLdJHOgDpshNY0WVFpWkDV2H6ASQsijpQNgq/neBiAxqk@UqNIKtBN8f5@0gKwpnXWh/bujplhIhMBbmLyHgITGVKD8kCYZU6bZZVcPj/daK61Gd/N7CpfB677NrO0aWDho60DOQdrg@zc0@3OUO9Ak3BsiKIbhjnwBeeBkng@8JbZDoQcFdEbql5XWr03mzb1CoHMM0mD2g/VnujbdGQXQhZXQNBCeY4L@KwFjdKgZjCdOgQ4n0lcfoVBpjLwSl6QhaBLByLjrRwaNxDwRdeCVnpBubM5o@O9ymzy4BRNHVi10g6Txsxo1bs5Sc2ETpiNhSAUrNHrcKC3RFDVKQeq/KjDcsi6158D2AmzCJw94qpmdBVo7waYfcd25gAFRIZgMci0D68HEK2OUdKFniiQo6ixhuJvWEVQZ8A1oOUD/XV9f@CVgPFbfnfYVIFSMifu@NA/spFYMr47tnyHm5s9p5np6x60z0yQQsYYNq3RTIHILazD1550DhJV22MVhqwXqC4Rb3vAN8l9DwNHvGSScggEf8sQkAKpgKhE2yNWfABM5XhsGwl5iijlNJOx7cpJMGDEEDVfQWlsOpuvwWk2lxgsmhk1g6EynmuQQYkImQgeg1O2pDtTRbtlHqU7sgyvtt7zTPjaw14PrUObc7kE7/yT7FK6cwdYW4KSs/qDnmVYfoP7srt3hZDAVmDghnJQG4WgJMS5I0bIKjAUCCN6Hx5a9Z1jkl4TSSjInauphE3XdVyert91oVMnBwwmRZH6xDobtmawaqMbolPGMQQKyIYPEi@Mr7jcM0ME05ia7XtZHDGFpILxOdOsMFnAo6SukQ65Yo3JIpoQEisia5EqTGCO0hwuBJ6LLR5buEULv@f0sWtjL0h8xPEADNQtGycsJC5WkFShz5UqQoGCpP94XH3tWHbiMr6yshIvxasgLqys7IBpG007aEqBaYdMCpkwnIomipEmE/rWKAa61eNXtQDyKFlHXjDCIc5ba5DQa6XSej2t1zTxzeE3CUQG3SWEVvADcOLJSgWNyaRcvYCCqs32dOn3sMs/NlxrIJDwFf1c53aBhXVCA1Ct42JdlBHny3HSr7im6sHQxugm3PhpLXtaP708baVOr@JpjJ0s65UmFArSS/TVjusMB4lssrZRUrR6MllbB1GsWYln42uJRFGBQSmMq5KfFJMpnWM7ETdBFEicnsYBqQI/NaPrErxROpdMhqiCfKC0ByOHRFy9LEL6zWQ9mYpD3GQ8DQPRSjwOmDEQCR4VGil/CkFHzz7jiNlLpSQiUBhj4@@aLAFuOISfjv50@PYtMm4OoxlSWG@o8/HgQATIHNpBWBU9Z4bggVezzbATmUrjU6fNx3h7@Np/dCCZI6qtT48O9p9VKJmu7p2BQKV0MGzG80Gc0N2WCu2oN2yZ0rwwwDPBZExygrMhmHjHMJjiMAqmGDwTkb7SYAugAaPFKQHVYUqvP10Erwv53ZsqAwEhd4q5THgzgizx4HPzFCZ5AN3V3vGjqUm//hkIU8zwejj5obi8AGDNrHHHFn1iwA51z7FaJXZII04bpGugLRCuW@HMhu3YCnYEweDUiSbEp3cgBLmhqIlilDUVBgG3rREM8GM4O4SyHw7AgISAgQHCbBhqm@oLYm4yAyaJ828wEps3FHrKpUjV8CatE0Y7YBz0dANY@DS4U5mdAkDgQJnMfJ9k@RpgGBlNDYxoVuKmMoIcaeg24q9l0ah7aHldRC8MpLALdNuAVRxy41iSsHbIDBDxO4Bpc2SJvgha@DFGeah7iSSORXf5IAupDAcImKlgLpKkd8cwhq4JAwX05ZM/bN8@t1zHRiSr@wAaWFEZ62AG@Dz0Ahnt7h7mHizG7zzggLFrzloEt1Gos8g1PGhdttNzOg5bgwBImqrKCfvQxjlb6LR9fQAtynpLCNrtOPZ4hgZNM5wFLqwjyfOZKQyZofDqa@gF2PxCTwIsKPPx4df3obfW8tks5D@wZekJCxmBMltGdDTYJIBY1@gh3WBNft0cdMfuFDl5jpgF8mkqlBomn5fTQX6GXIkW/paiRhs5d4F2Hni1AtO8su/TgAinIgfjBaWfEj54s4ESxmac0TVAxRTQaxU@qV9kXKeZKb4VVN250u47vp75XAUWjS8JhweKxWQvE1@JZxQF3zJ5sVyVZVrmeQa51ATyaB9naubAHpmmkUFf7NxYYJiLnsBzAWpO4bHpBcXk3wAHYczZ8ndSKWTslLswbZ5p6ORPukNTMo2uw@RTGF9FSyZDB9G1WqYCmAfpFwdlYTSxxiX5zhDGtC2zZ/Ut/5BWIXo2DtxUYt4qci3huwf8ZgLgqWXCaITPtkw6GVwpmPRRdoeHfwacnKB6PlM5Sl2zlVmbQHvsOG4Xp7Y0mlDJhajvC4@M4w1aqj8CADzWPvXvXtDPPzl6sN94unvysJIZem6mZzWBR7TMRh9G8j1oDgsezBvOd@4D7Vi207egRAHIt2e9Z47jc@EBl0Ju98QwYgDj0YPGo8P7z3affU1kjnp0qz/s6ZjH0upMgBDGMYVZCsZwmg7IFvZwISQQLo7uHz0KoHzl@aPD3caD/adHJxEwr4c9S9dGmcFZZ1GBvoJBmKZmOeqPeq3pNSoao09NoQhmgwPOMoOBOVMUeCvoxhPFIamKHigiY/eoKDinreOsvctyWnZrq9XUi0Wz0DI2NjbbervV2shpxXy7mM/ls/DaLGyZ7B0FVxRzRNNWYOJTQjh7hmlA5umjqRuBhAPjcAMklvHcfIW@SzJn5PPm5saWvmVsbW3puc3Wup4rbppmYbO9kc2aBS3bbha14vrSzEWygaLVxNan6S9odThTQp7A/BLwmWoOPPMg612wVi6XKxj59tZ6rpXPbrSaW9l8sdXUNvXmlpltb6xrOa1l5LRSEBd4LDCGTBcqDKVKG0TTwEvRwDMpBZ1ptIpp3TRYWBcMZ3UdWcwgWBjHgYPw2ECPoVgWB5iBex7dg0VxnJ8S7gV07@OS@ESSJWvoKAIWKSCujKtuM3DcQsdwTXxqtRhYpeCf8/wXRxKQL7XsFQK/wFX1SPkuNY3cz/12e8o5R85nCnZlvYnzOjnzNfXp1WxR2GtecwOH8DYIHl@LnwvvmtfcwCG8PIeHa/jzwc34zAsaAisQMFzznwtrxmNOwBDSJkGK7hOY@BXJb9EmAZHWXO@FkULYWwSbr/83XnsNFLUbYvkfqZk3kBOQxB45ID8/snDRoj3VYqRwBH4qycE0wvQsGvpw2SVzPjOyU87laDze9i37zKFxcmhqZFUtj@05jN0/612P2YaRBb2mgoZ5COSYBbnz@s02veYEwD52dhaSPGiKV/T00LPqmWf0wcneeTmYnraeSr5ptocw6Mk0LRvNNwRTtooUst1sWouCAiZw90TwnROsxJ4NYeCZUzdULRjl4jIRsGg@53xyeEQBmzqN2abXOtgU8v2h60Ms8f2v32hBJVyvoq4@pqFfaGjY5gVWl9JeWGMiKlroNb92J508IYZMN4E0dFwv1nuhYT5oqn1F6epuH0dYorqBQPEFlLCE1njO@dRL8J2fSIkRkqfXVJht9ZlxbS@N7zjMg2HzpG5mVoJ4ujS8xkVYwggfBFsmRXKx3nmNmCM@HIyIOtDnzMnhbP6CBRs22fLgd4f@kL9xl8NNNWoN8LestYqQ2bze1EwQjvWmZS6pf1c/G7YcBWQ8KjJmrDAn7KT0NE2ntHv6GTc20Di/@LyArtXpgCQhvouCXXRhVEPD0cwFfW4iEc8eegOlCZXlQxsiG7WK/pIU3B5/Lwpiib2AoWEx1qwevW5R6SFxEbmAMEeIxu1ZSgRp1gyae3pzjIP07sdTGSZIog2wn4qRSmXXscMLl7yjW6oWx8dekuJvbc2PzTeGcZTMG1hl@IYwhU8dU5nFFrEbKhb6MKuv95RcK2JcyNyDSeOJaU5QmrFRjJ7uAWn5ojrMc6g@ei0jd@ykDBhwuRPTEmKfZCfY@bBoEV1wMNGqDadnedi0e4uY6ey64yRN3JpHr8hktDUPsS2SlryuEprm8wXH8HEFewGh3YLL8cVjXJ6PUI7qLEKa4Vzgb6GU0XXOTf6e3@e9nZurW3AspUckYRlzO5fW9V4EnHgXT/OsHgj/QEw026rRUJfv1gi2J@QLgzfXawH3QtFrPvLP5hbGN3pz3acbTjAjEh3P3bIxeFbP8dgxvZfhEgrmefw9vxlE0W7ptkLLR1Hz/GgiUwOmiknZBcSg9zpOr1DsZHR4LaSYodvGjkR8b8syQ5anaTezvEC@cmxNfBf2FWcZ9@ymuqOVDBc3OESMS7rteXxPrGEuLiCQKO5aml@4g2yRYqoZPrxeVAGu0b3Qx8H35@iOFmE36I4GY5LXQXzECFtFMPgul@F/ntQ2lqfWuh1PuwZ286ZCRCr3rGdC70fva1XKclntI2No2eztOVy7NzSH5lwGd9R8beIG/yWjmNtnKiuKsSomR3ECCadGw1BvxfjzVrnGjh9tSxkMMFto5DeKR3P53QAE@wGO0J@C4Skarkfs2MPBVOVOjQLtZ8sx1x0ELdtpTWUSfT6WIxVvFsKmpH/PpN/SwRkfTOJSWGUjm80KoSgy3T1lWTZoWw/jvrb4eyphcpmkPAmLPacbMc5PYzLzClVvnXkKzoHejjvlFs0oUOCtrYxt2aY/xvctGW3TcXofU3vAb1sWynsgxeIS0U21eE2WEpvm2GTaxMNJl2Z70YQJ74vEaBYQh2P2ZYQQnaS9VQ0rKNxAA@3MWJdPIUWmfG9KBXp4mpfimyx6iwVVMRmjqUV1c2lj5OKv0zR7Ov@MChvL4G2p60vhhdKKkKtpFQxXzvha2WTtNTbDsgZjQJbVgkFR1@ybZF0ymtBbr4de8FkYaOTgb463SiuTi@INLOARNr6n1uUiUpTv2DCM83W3Y@I4qIfr58J1EV8O5t/nIvewr3dMfqZsGeOcTI3gDms@epwY50@SlPj@NAOi8U0iy0kBGtOZOfaC71yAj8cG1Oewf/Ms30y7N2hL000NXc3MXXa4QUy0u07X7ppdvmcotC1qHkCRPj8NuKwQkP9O12DEn6L7maKY7Tm93m0wi/yRc0vHac/N0z6eUWtB1I@CO9ab4CE@N84eQjdPCKL@flG76ZpD6K08x3cGpkK2RUF7OLnE34u4aLAM9PPOWi2dUQCMBN@fF75xU8SO7viDAX0ag97QoxdFVeho4ZIhG586pySJLpnjdtS3Tr@pCkf1gH8fQ4UvYDZNPOeCW5g4ZZsdp2l0rZsy3TR137bOMsEcE7cuHfYOIniymPIAndWeBeh1xyrSSyXqf4yfw0WVLqareMcWGuZTQYntDV13jJQezEXTlAFtyZqcWZ5wlen9GeFkMV/uQMOiXImVxzneJEPgzr1gh9qSNRexULmQLElqRwldMbMg5mgL562mto9G2tT6On8tkqZmyk@ZiqwPf8zEq9hWQVOQVmR@GNynaGpqsXtuF2d3hx3vOpPkywItEMzwNbf2dzt4CvwWlc8rGvoy3RafRXWQ62Vwvzx8G1CbQ3PpEk9@6RoPhdN6iu5Y8GnAB@p1uHDCrmcNPP5mSjs3V/S4vmx9PdR4/thb1FnLbPNVGDTdJDP2HRdPbYFwohiu6Rk4iY@8nUtinI/ZTgd4vNJjk8BB2LlFuL5SPpckwr5T@eKJ2dFxS@cjC3d39uZQCkCdXTC/CehXh7pnfXXo@OZceLOL5jeBe6x3LOPhFOYDYAFGxb4//plqCuh0HfkXXcujAzOBYcnEFRIZJ1ukswaMHOYN@WYWCsLj5cvnZiIil9hvzpRDFuxLDw24VIH@@ty05q0BOAMafI7JtGz63/Jpeld851LV/I0Hy5K/GPYHQ0985qdOe4Oik@P9M3L3Lixglcob4NCsq/f8@RPokeldkN5EZzoxLpLnv271nA77ejHLQNgD4Q3F@zkEdx@69ae6Dy3CnkPAlPYCXj67RIszJwrnkt4boAlznSmWbfnLZ4l8X4fRVvDFwvAOCI99Zh7hW733sRCUk/kYebRUkgUZYGz0UK0A33fnsaZrQhfKlRmEW@SWd2YG0OIxHf5HY6h/IEr9IjFzL1itEP2ObV5Ex39LF51K2Nk69tBX8HzB0uX0SSdTWNrJlNioWIjQCkt8df/x82SUZGgP7k0irgljzKHXG09MC7dDzFCiZYOUt5g5T4cOBioPTNIS8Yx2i94QZ3eA59eoD3jgzBtMPR27pn/r0Rj0KMP@A9PARdAb037iPAb5Dvq2AXDh/jOTH0@bYi7zI2K0R46h9wA/rRuTOSawczqPybhdH5hNqN/exDRfYJsH@IHu6wsELJqOpMFlaLqRVqxe03Rf0zxjxLxovDydoYfmiAYuiwmGN0jFNwwuleOM31RzmV0x8gaOY/M3ceUsfLTHy7kP9Bf0uv3iv4qbqKe6w7njv@nSHoXqB/jRyUXFdc2m0@NvLMKCntC2@D4H3bVML/PIsocjcitsMAXEufkjJL6bOKtukgoYaEjBEmu4zRh3zQneOTMMAzn5XPdoB8L8wc/Ulubb73fq6q7h4KqcMHzkmlzkbNoNbD3cs813SjShYkbA1HRjKE453ZTVXr/Zp9fCwUuktp@ZTTz716Szqb4@midZTp9hE44zp8gCtoaNv8AST2F4lLx5xmx2bDeNcWtAL2LqF3MJJUjuiWUab/XkrcZVkRZFU9YZnYbAcxvV9DY9kIF6puJ3cdNnxl82lx6cD56zIDPsm7gGPr0StJCUHK9LdODMX/UPWa1rip3juGsRGn1gRn6r7C4kVAQP/0f3v5KBLrlR2EDtCcOR0gFGdvM@A8j80LXF5zbE9tTx/LY1OhqgXizHXcRZsFh5iAIf3gjQtLaoEFB79rDHp0M6kW1l/RYN9UAwbDtg6hHz9k3FtM8V0hc1ul4ixyWVN5ldVLjmmy1FTJDgsobyKJDLwmDiO2ctN8omcVerluGIHRU2xD7Xeci98MJVSfBQBh59MwPv6eGjoxN14GlzW0EwjYm7FYdWD1cZqcEFboAYMl2T3no6NY5d8iTdQ1Pn3nLFbGTG7LXuRpZr@Q49PJeYuX@sKXuPDlUMsKCO@JKLAh9cTpz6LN7gMejqTdPXM/rCYRb6mv58EfPhyeNHqck5bZbY67pO30xGvfeOj9PAodhXjud6R2MfQItqO6OF0Q/3NS05h@Sf27SkuYi5zklpEaQTEwbLUGEP@ZHhG8UzwxmYrZPxwPwc@l5k8N4tky8sLOQT/dzqYMtlWwsRRY2bbamFjWRk@7rponqy4LuoPs@sAXJYgz4Z/lm4mwYFj/WMuz5f@Fi2YWFWCGJZsZHi4yJp2evU6lsKtIxOF00Z3ftFM6Zp2iI8H@ttqFeWX1hZ0wHmCSY95/wWy92mGP4ooZPiA1Up1o377DeVPrD7DL5w9UA4grG5cBfPMgChc2Fug78w7bFuK1yPwNLB9wB70yVBxJFE0gUXKhkC1sgPy4Kb5QptJJ4aKDYUJ4tJPgsG8OCoG8YQ55yhzaiMAiYSeiqVTEoi1kOQVPqoNQ0jeXRAHlpBmWUDI@ayC90PhUf9KAm2qrPtCoRIJstc0RCwUehShmaZta0AMHRhVseGDATpk9I3ZPdc2YfHYNDvB1BrNbZ6OSplS9oV6h4pyaxe5/nFhxLZHw1IY9szHr22qtcrq3FFia/GT@0Sy8bD4GbPM@cH16fCQmbxIzIcYpdrc3RIFWOIyzLXjwVSJyqT6@p2C1iDYK5QfpdreeIqxE7wHMWf/15L6NgjXZJ9y9N7gBBUlQl8vutc7PB0A3QNBrpLCtNIi1OPK5hS9naF6jWuWg8q6/nBSVHo9xJ6OcHylC9KhLngdIP7KfC4vs/JgucmPHotEg5jBYUynN6wb8N4p@V3PZUdW3QSf@hOztYJbaW27@KiaSvNDlnLxH3qpGCB9gj0HOcslID//Pe4VjNSsyCOvwfJk3rCSIqoTUEjVWKG4Qwh1wGQt6briCAJRLJu@EPcjEPaMck9icoHSN0a0LoSKBujZLjGsb3dY6bsszjqzEGVN2WrnVjdffbp57VsvfKe9TPmf/1GJnkpECd/Ai3dk9MsCFK@QsKKeufBe@IbZ/LqSOYJhjooLDHJcsHrA3WGciJDNRQBjTnOIGg2OGonhYchNQq9Qwk0Uz0H23r7pAOQCNa8IK1jdNjZRpGQlJd60MDAmiTQvNVVVhNDvklEOfZZHhJEzW061wHooM5Pq2@iBi2Msjpi7xjJZtAxaPks2Dgie6i0rV@5HzDE9ei5sswDszmkExbnOTWXr1BxVhuV7SqZYHDgoDbE2svTUS6rnI429@sZL0Dq6enok2zuC8C640KsuxlseftPHlyuqtXsu3eePmayfBUv83NwwCZWL58ePt0/Ptk9eX4MtXAVMLYDfho24DVIRXTAvev0SM8k4AVnBD6C/4S2CRNEbcbJpBQ9ikxBBa5lRV7lxghrmop9Q/R58T0z4n89gOBp0GFJYb8AVKATsSHWsPBcmyQTcYWCQKIyyyeh3FVDxOBpwzm8lFAlswogSwFk3RJVbHFhd7jbbTB2I5TlaNuZGwQxFqZXC/15Eeei4OofpNwD3fN@8XJzKMvLTWGWlBuChq5BnIPdw0fPn@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@LEmShRCal6/d7kYBzdBafmpkPv/5Drqf41Afzd4R5lL0Ptl8VtjaYfy3w0TSw/bPQlgPbd7ntZQar7Lou10k@Q800C0@wA3Hek68VDBlDoOSeChRWOVb354dPmWegYmOs0L4@itQVsplgnMKsPlDGOVU0BucpTOpxAidR@xzoBIgLiARlHBRrKD3TrSdQrWcpk8GM4yK1ShvZzRHfP0ZaPt8MUV01SGKZQr6woWUgk8p5AJB0b3XwMC4HmEyWgDFK59ag8qppsO3tbSZ7ht4zK4UyJ5DMqv5yXX4VZnQVwkp8tFBjEAeiTGKAX1VES6zqKS2JUbE3i2txZGwth9MbiIQJMkCQJDrbgbYekDkdgSogZhsG4iQ2jYNREHBt24kokg4AKQCIw@YqmKfb5OSALS6iRFqpGq0G@QUGO8ZgJXkexdZeslP/1K4L5doMqO9Hc@jXBvM/maNxm1MWaiO7rhk6MavXGUvD7h3bDq5HHUBuWSKXya1ntEIyQqGyAAX5xfb@DkBCCweOYZjWa2fg7e7tH37l6OnxNSV5FDI@GyzO4tXt1Kmipmv10BAP8z2N1PsHmePH9w8CVEZzNZlJwRCT0wOz2ZyX2mxOF6T@gp9lvp42eVxLSMveFjBtzVUO6ADOdegT30wk4B4/Snkt1UTy8qpW366e2rFryb@bp8Y9pq4hcYHp1CMl7vHZbGIWw2tbTvDaFk8NVHRoqJ8Dj2/7ztlE24dwiHjw4AEU4ACSmglCLWKekIEjPv8zUUuV4/fGeMT6@BwR6eIOcxQJeRLcMINNa6JFVagP7epet2c1JejAW6hPmCv/CrRbhWrDVG/Qs/xEUhIaZ0GUQG2v4p6ZUWmk0s6WRBKbOcFKs2UaSQN4SQkaAcCLPx16XfbUGURmth6YgekZSCPswZDvcjDZV4Z9CNemzzOTpnlBPlEgMiAqHmaVj6qhZQmFpKMUKn2F9GqollQUXO238olRUu2ao5bVAQaeSKahpX@igVgVqkzBQpOSUjsOPI5j@FM8jRpF6UfppR1NgOs1XbXsljlKoKK1Uh3kU3SPX7w4jyflazRAynH3AnWaM1pyg4ao@6JFTDTMzjS2rfBymRltw1tbqKyuj5umKwxSPPbdR2CE/inR7usDlhiS7mqPqYysidOEnfZ8N8mUKtcAZbNUikbV8CEPkJoxaJtMRDgsgbOQiUwFagddPbuFn7fWgNU0Va2DmRJJslWcUduDrhznopISjJIgSonAVrBuWQlzxKlX5ZQHcdBfIn2SDBU4z/EmrcO0guEgLqjUrHo3oodv0gI5Vre2SqI2plnNFgOyuM7l1QyAncNCAikV8CtUegDW8I4RvIwGF1OBLdz7zLRtExAENNPXoQ/Wh0BkbjIdXCyVntxJQSnEeBYfCh0hkNHpuyr245c93GuzminT5Ez5CvrUV6fYqbZFtzrO/PcZNVO@TKz2KuMMCDrJamK1W9FS62up1Kq9lli1sau/exfndK5WQZJoqDBEGkEgZbWXLAM9g@RRWbXLq/p2YrVVya1RDLDCIO0SIrz3Murlqn6VWb0LPXUaXFzeeBOrHikIzqqqdgX5wxaymkkDzVyiPlW6VQqTX7VSKcyDutrADLzPnB6niGefHmdo@qgspNFMpy@a2wxXDWvi2p1aHIHCWVQ0MPYcMnZx1KoRBEaVS8E6@xy/BbIHT/gzXH5htNJrelHxX572uT1jEfwuTrobuTpmrqEZEDhKABLRmtaTSWAmP/tZTCswObG6U1jvnafi@WwZXlo5z/Lsk9VTRcmt1mIsdm@1rut@AwbumbXL0wfFzjkz27nCm5rVVt8UK0/TZ/WnT79433j/cjROnibisb2jd7K2AeE32Rb9bvtsstyC55baDWNrGSmWWdPubmYyr169AqEXn1pVrQZB1Pr798lavF7bxDItAhRP5HLJY8uyMux04LVa8Cs7XUb3vNVj/EmlEgq5wEupcbednf6ojYbRrtnpDPf1MXe3YkP8HPgi7uOvv3jxAg0v6GFvn3F3FuMQmQhXauj5GMtlc3/@k5Wr9OXTxvaff7OfMVfwc4Sf71w9RvOxlv9kZeWT@/c3NtKALW5@@vWnX9vd3d14kM4/reV3NpTsyvaf/enKSi63ncus1D1Pq8drZ1/IueyGrP75j@ONp0@/6nlYYfisMw2M@C7CT2P5PDtjb@E5azP8J/PbVsSso7nZfstib2OapsXG9NfAdQYcWFeI@Uw/K0yr7mz@t@8dvYn5sWou88KFrx97EysUY9wIBrCtB7bzWDW2jcEKV7FxplKpgHHzv/1biF/9CsBBn/E2vKr5AFZhHKsqFYryLlYtgEHL5SDd//sb35jOy70aPPLGZk7eqcOzRs82Y1KsOgLvavXwgOWquTVBSlrxrnY3Et32uyCMnMa04sbRPbJapkNfG7/w6LbpZzQtd8pJlVMO/@KcSmzi3AX8Qb0zJzYdlMzCBcK/iBENARERHXGzcCDS4g4vZsO9ONX1tc3URu6eXX4hntDwy3ue4VWFhZV7rx5kMttVkAfwKZXunQbNMMM2i7Lj3MMpQjZCpJfZoxDBVTlbzMnpdPoehh8p@IxiEwwyjiQWm0JtjE1sLOoUY0E0NgnzseH28fmLf/8X3/@L79Hf9@n3n6RYsF9OqZ3Xq8EDNCRXXfnyVFhHUw@wqfozpmU/fRfPr8ePwQSNSAt9JyWKxapVfNG/sJGJvjNuwqcaWijEJMr8cEywogCpMSn2PpNhWCXsPCjOvZXSSrFUKOUyDTZTkntQTXJuc0uuV3P53BFUnSZTxW1FQgG33NlZgT/6hye04nuFXIQzBbn@rLDqrZ9ZFi/FarFavc6bdjVaRzc9z1SlDLSnkqURLXfsXIopwNRSqWdA2kyQODynqRuf5ylVbQgzGhz4OoriAFQp9kt4qhKLXcJTf79We78WpFyrCsO2Uq@mRIbgozbu1VPK1VVNfZkql8U/SI7l0IYPfBj8oCD1K0XZfgnAatNg4xtOvODcQ@gcOL3VxsttAJ/arm1XnD36qQ3ErlJ/Wa1tT4MQmbt3L6VCLdwDANXVOkuCWKooK7WFZQCA9QSDoQ3U8dX2VfWqtn11tb0N/9v0vhJfcL3avvZPn8mzIMzEv45UdVrLVE8zorVX62BXM1V0UTOnYKjCF8JBryPFLpEgWa2u4FCrotS0Qr5O0gV7zB7zx7bhH36BFV3Q4TG62fxl8xBBmNCZu0ixNWCymZK2llvP5EefFPZzwKk8TDony5k1NLzDvh9Eti0phuOgLT4c2iKHVx@@/N/xd/rhyz8AK5QT73sl3@Yb/Hv0Fv/e@Ph3YuDfszf4x07e4t8zH/8eN/HvqYd/J2/wb7eJfyd9/Lv/Bv8e@/j3vIN/UqzCGMioqzvZXvY8q51pZ2CwWBaGCN1sV2sBl2RZk2XH2THL9h2tBSYT/rJgsrJtlu2wrJ21NQ08weCzrI@mNnw68NcGKC78WdksAs@eM0ilh7yXNOLT912DJU@lGou/MkGsVDU1qxasRh21a4EsWY5lTk8zXNpmuY0yaea6umKNxv6TB41GBtvv6WPnaPJ/dNSPWpf@94@cx0dO34H/o6Ojx6fAh6upeynlHjyVampbfHZi1fLOaUlBeg@aViyzvXNaXVfQXEhBa8mhW@ojnwlE@FZXTqX4BfTmF2USGsoX5@WLMhlCKzc0RAARjBsgVlkIG@AC8U5fZEg4uIDnnOCSDY0X4BmYuCHz4uIUxWUYIIX/gI6o9R/g3/r/1v/j5yxRqyehDVxebSfoSeJfMnl5dXkl3tVkIiEsiW34QwewY5TLqyoaKdAlmGqJZD15dcXd4J1IbnOAVUxju0qRJwGBM8XCNCld/kr8w34xbfGcxssgLFdWE2Lh8/R0lM0my01wCVc/9He0hpYs0@6i1WZNq//Zj3EWRdtJUqD8RrmsrXFzbiNXLm8Iy2axXC4K82oisXX9qWZ3tAKINRsbyWS5DJadAGYWrAHMIsAU5jyAND3dKGO7L8eSmH/ODBJZnJKl65Dickm@ezchbg/bGQySd@9qW9l370KnRqNluY0Guq@/eyc3ZNybVNnKgz1bfPcO@FA86biJJw5fFU8oGvskV6UUthwXSrkJ3kzL5CZpdnVP93038dYapGXche7JSbrCIJt13NP4T7/7zW@exiu4W4VcNzQEgKmw/PZ2YaNaLWyAuVAERMirfPtTopPa0pJXqxmZF5fJq/GY8NKKm0lyvYqjP4tts50qNF4PH3Z5FaMqZRv5ZKI5NpOX4BK4aVtb3JFtFBLF1Jb4q6wkWXWNiT8coa2nNtY21@7hEG00/0F2W77UK/FMJn5VudRLOIF3VTbEhTl4YFS/e3d9C1BazJZPpUbjwe7JbgNvDsbtCdAPM3Qk3i3h0vPAjddotjW/Va9h8eqn8XipfI8qXyvmWSxeFuGUOHQDrLjF@4CY50lWG4@OjwjszG8tNmDa5jr0ytApSwPaKraZZS1cbXeZ026vgCNUIWvixgjP7PWCW4YuHLfXurBa5ooUe/pod2//JJ3bBnkhd7C7l84dP78f09Can9jJex3tz/Z3Hxw9hwhPH@3vHu9/evj5/vOn4O5Jr923umnq5tA0GxfD4cUb9tqyGhZgrze0LMsxXMhEwzTNAQQLnrJpMtOwPP31a90d0MM4I//wo29/@NH/8OF3vvvhd7794Xe@/9Mvv/9t@P0e/L7Lv9/9N1t5fP/0y3/2ux9@@3fA8T/B74/h95Offvmb3@A/sv8J/P5LxO1PxC8Sjv8kgPWrP/3yez/@6Ze/9gP4/Uvx@8H136//ZP7v@99a/MN43/vd5WG@@2/h9/scVhD2u7/N3fB7Lfxv83C/9oMPv/Hv@P@fiT80/s6H3/gTfAnLP/3Bn/2XD9/8D7lc8c/@9Ydvf/fDt7734Vvf/PCt73z41j/OffjNf61lo6/f/fD9P/zrP/r9v/6j/4X@f4/ev3@b/w8/@Kd/@X/85X/8yz8Sv5/A79@B6Sd/@R@AdP/uD3@E/9/7w7/74x/h///2r/7uD//F3/3q/0qGH3LD//Mv/w1//82v/@e//a3v/PVPvvG3/@Inf/vDP/zr//PX/q/f/M9/8z/@wd/8z99Exx/@5K//@Ff/6pvf/qtv/fO/@uaXC97fXvr@8hbuX/4SXG6fz9vAuU25Ptbly58rP78INiapAJ3QNUEsByLx/bHJylKWZRl/QTv9/j/58Ju/AuT/GxAQbP8T2OCfW8DrO2RhX3yBvDHqz1I09aOkvvgC/cVw/guwxao0Z4e9RDFXTK2BlLy2tRVO5m1PwHwHYrzLgGyfvfcOQHxB8fnDvgiCQd5@i4JBOCaCBeGmM0lhcI8sd//pl//8x@QRxkXnX5kCmQ2co6FXMfi7AB3fQd4wKW409HeQvXz40Tc@/Pgff/jRDz/86FexP1E2ttK7aZAKls@RQ8D8LcJhwMJtwkFADce8bIWtSDkwrGzjzK6kpV69gtyvgAkGcGtSfh1sklYls4ZmiJgCG@PTfSl8w7@0scXQAi4jcoUvS4HX/RSrVCopaVTByUEMClaMM2LVIs5A4XxLBeBiJB4n3SjC2IiN7hMUiFlJPWONtcqIR0yhQ5UgIF1J6PRM1nJyqlh5AAlWRg8YwkLgKekVfF9VqsXKqIrg3lMWAEbqPiQJoSqYu1H1PdgrBBPCS6MH7yErxUoqVS2CSwULmaLU0g1KU8tT4ajsKZYSE5/wxb2qO/cY@0TWijKfIgVUMhEa36lJaAwIwcH/NLUmikP/gZF@axgf6mlE@OFu3H8HnSm@CABwFQW3OMJPUTA398B7xEGlKFn4pDgEwFyKz4Cx0IGEnJSUovpNkQXShzx89AMgt6sSL9Dq6qqEVnldbhzBoBRGf@5ZyfN1FxdhSQotMbmwJaMz7hgLCogbC1ef0hh27cEavDX431@hXeBUpvKatBrH2Zc4E6l@kuK/e/fW2CeAA/pO3CSmpNadDSfGi7udSsk5SLjqgG2NipoiQDh/Qf8p6WVMYjGiAWg0af6Gj1ohdwbDe5FfcnhZkTBnuXUN7TgXOxwOMYaqptV0WnxV@pKDKgwq@YqvukrSJj@D2sMTIsE8xZbER1hMK2zQ8SC6uDHJklLMMFGMY9Jjr3PfGcEwJi3Laa2AK3lJMWV0UsphK5b2S1l4f80plSrvtY1NCb5kH@IFkuJIJ9BT13RNdXsb6aJ6qdAkGRpB/i1I1arYz8A0qXq8fwLBT46YlsuqDIZAlxubuY38Rj63XijkN3PaRmFro5AvrgPHLWTzuZy2tbGxVdzavJrPne6l0/JmQd6u/qNrz3/3j@Y9813xkapfsJGKyxLKlVTtVfgW21Xc5iCfZuUyzd0RSldr2TT@5dbX4Q1ZTmv5zfrKSu9SQQyc0r7OS9xIArmWLhUGI8Y78DDpjsTugBM8kAYu9DKxNefwqCy2YeB92HwrhqzlgdKhSk6B1Dk4aRB9ylO2AVDC5eVl5CfFVr7@dZ9VqzDYUQ4PpBi04S4LdiUoVkvtqnRrc2vomuTbYaxlfW7h1TRqy/IGPX0MFJpVpdjV1VU7XCUjK4/RwveVQS5NMF@NdOn/f355Ty6n5NaVdU3R1vH/BkMO/28fPgf/OXxDrPWctM21M1Xx9lZHb1XCG85ZInnZqrQcg46NlduVWl3Fc@3lltp0WmPV88cwFBcEVIk3e45xFg88Lbz2DQ@VVjJ6Rm00gAJ9B8bnNKLfyW3mSysZN6PilvpEmyV3coVNcDm1AydwyaPLy2mnrVJLDXL0GNoKxMuVcoX81bZQ3liF8mC@qpiLS5G5ku3Y5hVuoy7pbeChlwbfflSSc/miXK6VJ3ZgM@X61b2@2bJ0dprFU3uXcyMWCvJVEA6SxtE9zr@wRB@vasL9@aXsaTa5IHIWIkOWKafSttAIVaUNJTVghnW8sLZW3w50RVWl9@/fj2gPV@nQ9sVmrtxGEd2ZhNMJd0HkuqtxY74wMWbReIJ6vZ5A3QELt9kjPJPhO@zE4Xv/75vGghB7XZ3u791zHc/7BcLc1@0z7vXA4vqEQq@HOl5T4PUtv7sgxPNBH4/Zmu4vDcJ@vwkZRJriAe7Dy@05zrwAm@z50wWlfBzqA8R9X6QQEII/O/z04Unke7K/u/dQKrD7R08ezHzyIlCePdo/OAmtm9w3iJoPQXxt/9GjWav4gLxQpomvFZbfxH3fgQX6e93XZbnGRvVyDPDiX4F4XW7Zwx3t7l3tqYsHKwpso1pc38yWSqfZ8hUUqXL/rDTAHeSeOVjzqvujgbe1AaVkQ/Yc8H5RRrU2sgxt8WB3D5teJl6JQ2sgxUcoXSlsNVeOFf/mt34POnPBYaTHuPd8S@MHKS1PotPMeF0sXg3tS6h9qOVc2HRGtNkbmmw4YAsd4YNOaHStTtdn/oUTBJCaus7g97EPxDejj7/cwedpkNs1n96c4LjVyWqzrKSSOJfbKuaLW@u5Yrq4VdzIa4V8Pq3l0tpmcXMLRJCsVtQKxfyWli5ubK1vgMgEvvmtTSkGooPVzmRATtVkGb4lAGsbeOXZNt4d56jdqhTjc9TsbUJPspge2odMNiGOjHftej4dr1mzKnJuA8@@gdwKEHVmsNjBwV724ECW76MFV9X2srLcQku@mM1u3pdlk3z2QKzLybLD4xRROYLsc0s2e39PloccAOoulOUuWvYLOJiWZQste7sHB5hOGy05jA/BzrgPt/QCyyYEs9Gyvk6jcVl@E4KDcLs8oQ3K6T5aME30OeA@e@Any58G@clmAcIzHo5DeBiUdXdXlg@5ZXcXffao4Hme1c/QskuPLLtgASKU5Q4YOtgxyHITjEiKsmyAyRjr4IbXy6H6Ohtb45gjCFEkyyMKrRtnMowZhTsm8/DhQ73rt8wOf8Yu/0K7OwQfazTcP2h@@mmz02m64939T5@hz97eQ709HrrNTlNEazbgcSAO@Jz1x7MP5PGw0dB7c30@Ax97xqcxbpiYt4b@BvIkng4m0m/sgc8e@Myb4ufQ4OlD0CY@9/vwva83ySd4yIe@o2ZTLiOhov4InJDHNnNmAy9I93XDdcpoH1VWWDwRT49rhWy9TO6sn2DJS@Bj6N9O0I3lOM4CoftyXBtVsvXKqLKZE2f0EvLpKJe35PRKf0fbAjFF39FyG6lRCW@4cNpxFle0nYR2d@1t4glIJOsbJfl0Z0eRa1p9J6cVS4XNl2tDWU6W8L2zvll6C0OvOIyv8JWsbdZ3QPaZRNncTOmZXGlzE4dl5SvAiA99U3Pom41GInFh6mfJJOYYe3yQx6i4bExFtcrtxCg9qvCMsTHEH1W0MtenxLLXgLVQld8QbwfmIDsJxMBoJ1vChZGErG0VZchCJpNIJpExISuB76sXwYpu@IkYpoz8UVlJ4ZeLa8VCUsVDXw2n3aALVtmraMjJZgvpBZ7TJB0NwXZqmhDwStIJDjuxRyA5y2oCl@EaN0bSiGvsYnyOUtvckqSqGGo95Tc@loX104d7Koy@hA2VA6oH2As5rrqHbG/KhyuuC5xOoNtTH5q4SdoI3Pa49gR1fwSjbOzKAo9AyZMq1OyoJw/Ll0oDF1O@enJ2cvKFchUFewzDTp4RPGVWJm0iqK8BVSlaLaZXqmDSUaqkXAIKkheEjka1WmlU@mZ/4I@hzEG8z3iHOwF06PHChKffKPolnggVHo1K9moS/smwz@7zQHRsNIjWqNwH/GbLNmomNtG6ykaxkVRtoZ7F@5X7l8MSSqZXZbNiuq7jyjE8a7tjV4a2p7fNp6aLxzwPj1ZZm5l4oNLovjrdx5B7KGJfKVWX2VP5SOhKtZmcdopYEXWJr4YYuaSDCrj@dwUjlcTLZPkN2NxVlmip95M7G@VW4j5rJMEl@6r9qs1yrLBRpst8EggJOAJhDjGiJyvVzwAwh3tWKkFGBEmcAUxMaBVqxGqRj54cWFflTqWGod/ha1uR5bqi1N7VpWpZqgKDKY9jesUbNvkt3dmmlssWyiNw0zY3yl3WrDRfjspuZQADdFbuQbWLWQl@@kLHnfiAJIDz9l3iw698gyW3lXyFO5YJ2LseCBMNtVEZTWpovVLLbRTSucIGTmIU1uGnpXPrOdxcnM5lt9I5DWQKkDUgPvw2wb4BPwgDIkdOw6mORC8hMyans6OsqqU1U0snsq@s1qtk@gznmkA8JKQl076zbwPlgAMSEJAtWeGrJ1O5tV6i5TB9WyEaBqZXpoLq6S4bWOkugnlm6j0ePKmw9bVEbzWBYVZPhoP9Wr1UAnnzq@iVUN7sFFKb2dTbZLKcWGHJime@ISwjfyQsDFaAosUMDvOG/Vp2BcoNbVC5gtr2V7XNXKk2XK0pGhQw@66zLVflOlTXFZPgL7rADGJXGdwCPsgFtYmoNXEboKTdM6Fqta1cWQSRBoIxJ@TEqRwcFkrE45u5eDwZL@PE5gq4C8ZOLDgOvUL8rrYjg6gnl@StnAw8fcLPr2WBT/0VNCl2JeFQl21sSbFL6eryaju6V/IzNh7rIIGL5y5jndSqxDK0KUhtxNgKmRS1SjPQu5XdzrPdsgi9uyfFSrSxd7Ltkp0KdQ9Myax87Fak1Hb1Jf@e4iY/SFYiZVw1VqddBKZFaow/x9NvOywO5dLdfi2XW6/XcpvQpwMjDoLmclB071LiCOeb2TLbqSrLnEqyTCyIb2oo5pO8FOx9jBo927sM5jlKdJ0ES@gl3shr9eT7J1bvsriu8AF5IvZ@NZVhKu0XbWTex6CTvIrxrea5ma3mVDnBxuHPXuXyUF22EzjAiNwHtg9dbT4v0xTtK8YGx1svN18WXz5@fvT86ADnOktafBsHcO9WnLx2byWbLRVLxTIrs/f2V77KBvH1jTiU5LQSG1U2xPkQrVpVtO0c2wGqZSXg9m2toGTfVTkJVsmjkAOfD7/yg43RdhHsORCYS4DCfCpXrWpruWRs8OHLP8DzwZf7n@8@YnHU1vL3f/rj3Obf/@m/oh0h8auyR1OFmzEIiUatsBm7vBxcXl7Bw/3ysXqM52ljMwlmvtNGi1UzMbGfRtvUkjFPEVZtMx/z3okouSyeLgDfvSPuIBfy0AZi@8@sfE67t40o10KUs/Bv2/S2YlKs@PjVO8bAYlRbnY6VI1Mmw0rvlW38Zzhp/V5ZYa8qVVwbY1vgGc6crlWr1TVyjldTePw9lwfP2lW5nmI09WqaL01zzV47nZqcPrXByfTW8I@8yb7meWANbObaaw8yyfJVGH6vZTKZ0@SHX/nNXK7w93/66@8a7xpfAE/e2toqaLnYzyBLS46nBqM2mgHCg6ZoCEd7bMH9w6ohSzG8lLrNePhg7IejPVTOwFVboU06dyyhv6gB6NNB1E5QsDU8ZJcmoZtO5CfLkhRKpiRUux0jTTDYGqpch4YkXUp30Av6M1YBFibdmYAChz7qxDIaXm/oDkg@TFA8rZ5mdyEKpHAHtais0OFAwQcVrcwya9ej8ixzhUokgbC@6XmoRg34tHQHojwCGqYL4NhAxwOmGNKygfGqGITySR6tGqRdh7R7PEKDXBNUeh4gzXjueCQbhG7pDp6WI6kcumlmbUOAMktKdwABUIaEAGzV2TZbT7JLK5UqT/SuXeEOSFS6oQfH1ySMhtBaeGYziFzGcBbXrTJ0Ud8YEzVsmFHHAAiHwVfWKjBewOhkQzGHTqjeGhTAIk0FCSoau3t3kqtKxWolGZUI4aPSOdQVN1GSdS0BABYMtj5pleQ0s1MprOw702QHGE9RdoHqFDJMArXxHCFaryQJ/m9NtEiRM1VFHmUsgKgv3ioMQBlERrTzOjRQbZ6W20yyMPMG5N2gTJH@nXAEeTr6RCU1WAbP4pX0s1ignhj4y0l0nCPodvb8IoNeaoiKY1E5A2cG4mQiv@cK@dShH8QOY0FRrB6FblsujBhoPTDQ5JNY15IYrR26UD6IK@c2GG5AzCfxQ7EwNOp70VF3ikhnhSa5SemcN3BsUrZCB9dx3yapwPMkrlqGZ3toX@ikNo2nQrsaIzniuuiQ8klVms31wXk8Lq498osNBG7SzOyopFUot8USXLshzknaIbgkRaIMwzhRRxw3e2YfsnRsmgwVfnilTKYDEsawSRo@HltAV90DC3oL28uIm/cyF9aZlTlBpaeK0waxVZwojaFQYoXKtoQaDdKV17POTD58TUwdCfZYrpAGsTANmJ38ALEl7ODx2G8WvNM8FPw24bPJjcV0JO5KYpy8/l3XVhINrNF3XG2Vi7frnet2BL/0vJPEoNMbe8F5fzqACnY1ZLnQMvkhvzie8gtPo0pCMUGFDs2rOHU@SIBsFRxTRSNIouY5hFA0CfsYYJpGcH4WWzGU9g51ANT2oGWhQhzfLeHB8gqqiksY0PQEg7fZJ2w9J5HiQFK1IDQjAAys@so0dPCDqFgOz29Bxah85gH4CrTOfgv8YqgfipMfxg@oG82kHGpC3mxFgMNOh9KqMN4sAks@YsHWwVX9QdFXwLMAOZyTk5WEnAKwKTkpc9Bh/NnonNol4iUldh1SmiEEgWqAgqLCfd3jykeFNpuLiwuVFCoNXUs1PVSG7eGtoZlBxwIZ1Mn4Zn8grjSy8GY7cWvnxKRwFfh4v@zOiK513bo75l9JauMR7zdDyzUT8bYXxz7wHPU2d/qkrQL1SHhENwcWqYQ3ErT07Akyy9XTlwGZlZDMlGL8CoEwhmBG6XHaSAOwdNM4S7cvWmXhwS9EB@BQWWbgiLoO3cDS9wKTNWiHIRyfNkwH9mbvzHB6DooeMp9gnSTNSxiEHAdWYR9YI4hkmxds13X1cYL8kxga6TQxJumGjaF3Jx8wQm/CLrlKMGtUG9enoo/C6NB3hQuuLuqqkC6XA@Wa2NB/xP1H4D/i/qNJokGytVGdS17odIXFQeJG1VNBSAQzDsJccUVyEx@CDCIy0zgIDDmecruCn1Gh2AG@uQ3qsRIQBtAE6W9MoOLI2mnd9syLtXoq0wGalgkRUOMAulYnnF60QjNiv3feGzjelJONmpmg8xH5RiejK6iB0wqWMawgIgyOLwsV@HT6Kp9j4f2@KDBAQHELPFEC2PUTVrIcKs4lTyCcmjzBMc9YTWSmTkKW8BJuIBVx1HPERgHVI4DQPSwSZBN8WNByxAUHggm8cPGW6SCsQhcWkAbgeD0OmJxpKpyllKmSIrlSlCCbgHaUSiuzRQn8oSpqM16RYl6J@o9mf@Wjs9@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@NJkpgC5MNSBM0JCEXXRgNvgms0Ep7ZaydLoUZVtKpIh/G4hONZMEXiAx8SQI8GCaf52jT85M0wUSOqiHZiGWeJo4HwjEMiuwyYlQHyPPh2QVRhnjMZCZKqQhSNm36Crq3pOn2nA@IdqiHF2DPgDyewMUP6YEB5STMdh6iliN5Yag4JI60nRdTPPjoq@yyX0JNh/Nw0gClkpJk7i2PErDsnucbC5Hi0IL3jj8/vcTS/x8vzS6Pq2TzzoXaFe35c0uuJCQQIOMnG@s3ZSAut39eyM5WV0BkFKB7h1lls0S6mFuZ0F4LuiuBqG@gjHdo80kUkMv75Ivwvr8Ag@v5tq0/HizGPx8Bv@rhZLkG3MXjB8mACgh8mkfdcTy4k7Qe3TAvC4q0jBygrgLxKjMtGRVfQMAcwjPbkcGVEAL6B5nF70jW6pz1LFe45J0/ueZqd5RZX0YNGy@zpY7OVECHTEbhBiZ/ByIz41e0KjoyOmJ7DB3UJ6KSSUS3ZiHQeqLSAZPT0eURH@rUwPIgVUg/NfFMODxfjD/2vsWacsqvw2WcQ@OPxGKnTp9sPBuPBmCsI7ZGe4YCP8v6H1ySeyL0ZIYAHsbMhPUk2uYx9PkuERbpFjxCGVaeLTKrAgm7L6Q@u1@HHoejmkkLlRiJVglqeUmG@qMatZTUeoYqAJvlSz@1I8iaiuzXNRUiNA5uwsL2P60KuQcYdDYaRiELkLktrzLGv8QR0o3k3e0Gv0pjDUMOYxOl8i8bVJF8kJRwCH8IXJ5A@hy8C7Jh@gxNUUDacoxK32zDy6euDiNQiXEAaBygRLAYXVVA2IqGkwAzBL6/CNI2FaRrX0jSm0gxbwHSSkUCSMZWkqAWsnmVV0DPb/gLujF44SIbPMrYNj@3oLk5LXMateMlKs/h5vAQMOW7GS/sJYMrxVrz0gAxevHRMhrN46TMwTNpW/F28FDQLDOCClQz30F2wcLQb8dJeInkl@XiXSJCuGi@FdQphdriVMAKowHKD1IhLZrYjium7JnRsJFSmGVKMl8ZxEk24pOmXhX9@aQC/3AY8cc5yjQKzFNOmOo1Ij8HTgW4jUCc7pyWXRG@@f3RAO4ImtzKAfwoGc9E4BB7E8Fh8mhnxjKEvrVDAFzKIfLM0P0dMm7664xbZEakDhVIlT6dP2FNJHmglyL8GgevJ6RshRPygvqZB8Aq8XT4x8qJ8XstOkBzlCNdYk3OyhUh9FV9SKKzrmetOeO1Ha4jmrqcD4b2xQRBeSwQ2wtNBhqPFNkxs4AymiYR8cZ@fFY1Ds2@8USL1zkQjriBa5gJvchYlQ8YQbfzJZcWJxMOsTbEg9Kxl67yVhf0C8WL0mvC6iKTKGx9kIcJzoIWbxpmJZPtAGCkcZzdp6isWdUNBXJ4kca5pNgmRVVQtMtR9nno4eN1HhSMfN3wNYo5wUiWBACIxw1Q4f3U@Qn53uPweCNQBEmYSmCdYz@9Kr4vXS3vZmZz3Jsler0D0TLMHybnCUZjCBOUwOohI5sto7ZqIj1s4uJDPEw2hz0j7AdrCMcENeJsdW3BYKCW459OOZzlwPMstRtR1iaR3rgZCi4opCTi84GFOJ0Vbnlde8HlVjD40ka33PrqC3ekKjlYewqMCuDMo560cT3Li2takbZOuXnRBlqqVGGfktPwZVvPEEdg9LcWGy7DgcNR49uDoyaOvQae7ubmZFH30eJI/bLU4qRr24xwy7UYO@4M5w5ZcGnXV4@I13XOMdzCvnNryNV7CmTUIA3hHT0B@oo0nBS@L8POZtgvxeNgIRgWss0kz0Ke4Eoo6OnbZlsCrDwgx/cSaLoAE4i3gO02jtSTOyQJ14HV/jQZ1X40GbkZqNEQvhlUTrHAnfxZbyQw9l66z5Zq0LySJjmSzB0fsxcPdE3bycJ8dPN/7jH3t6Dl7sfvkBI8wP31@/9HhHoPf/pPjfTaZUcAHbxfBASXg9YFpmP0mXnubzW4wgrznDMac7yT2ktz9WO@zh45h4nrUtqf373W5RbVNv8pj7cNwdIxzmBZdYNO3fJ/fzGcAOBJuWnR@Dbf1MwjbhDFtH8e8fadltS0IK@HYd2CZXnCwivUsqEHgt8HRyTQXkvCmE9oKRLfc0QWFeMMdhMdFGgCje5MbFS2PRzBbKhOIC5@PxuDJ/rPHx2z3yQO2d/TkweHJ4dGTY3Zw9AysT792@ORTwOfh8cmzw/vP0YsCPj56cHhwuLdLDjwDWZXhIXW6snBZFlQMTlgxznCJm661Dm3RWWcIBhI8u9DpJJ/H4kMbuY@l96y3ZitelvAOJH56kNYEWHgDITPf4FJmsOZL@wnk5x7d4rOaZduUGjSWKrS3smiu0O2hPnVceOiPGd7mZJbpwHiCzJNbomhTTssymbyHe05w7pufK6e2HICGhFYANoIKNqBUGF1OEI@ntwlkFVIzeg7qW@Op8U2BwoJR7wVbR8oSYUzsfUGguNf/0Mb5IK0cOgDdg0NOJOu7PABbDx14ALbBHVAUPcS9ICwvQgz9oyGyZ1bgDq/7gwNa/2WbocN9nUaxRZEnXm9UpToLL0jBU/Y9ul6Cz/LQrVG6Z1gWRfEoPF7P0OsFVzc2TSB54Inioi3cqwYhZWA2bVxqENvY7CE1bPAFasB9P3rb91iiklTZCW72MW2L39vR6ek239I02YpDtMeKqFikIjZlW@GFGHR6YuAQAeIlNdP5COM9EFKhedt4EPP@tRR1seeRLlUKtpTdlIH71zLw84ABQMrUSMegnoqOcCIYpy1IOeE5QJE4b/s@Gh7IuTU0zKkIwcWar623b5MCyempcVKw75ByB1WEd5Cm@Zpl23GhjRNb7eNZFOSCRtcZ@Bavw8R0CSbXokFo7NggtVeV6lRqdBXqTIq2Y0cSbQIVL0i1CUR5m1SJ4vkieci@grYe3stG@@gwO3oTr2ierJ2lcRHpwsTpFxCE@Z2S2NvQDcFC/pQmvOM93fNZrFQf3D9V3r9K460SnC3wm9SCTYT8XtA@pgXNg9b5aAOii3KXaGnB1STesImxxZ46wS2xlQfAYBzYtWBcd69RDv349uHr7njIZNadHN@9q/BYCnImzpGHXjcx4W5pVguSTFOcOhN7PSK8EzILvD4RuKQJZsiv7@F5EqyFMmDERj5CN/pOXwkiWEhQuuawDZxFXPolqjuEn2RV2joRCJL0JKL1kXmZuF9JVZOZyc4RFkFnImDR6QAy3gk22X9C/dU1cA@WgwP@fXtwxaW5493DR0F7sBTaR@VNSS2GxbulCKzbg32/BCzv3H4usFD29GLAvJO8Di2k9JA406uxcHfs8hRfXas7ansABvtenEEJgUZSG9q0RB1oQE3wCMkomIlAdHzyYP/ZMybz8QnEBb6HQ4aWYIMIe4XfmMJ3z1o2MTs1FJrCwXIoPAUuU1vXgmdZY56LvAWsQsggaYGPkFlM309KXE/0LCRC0G56YogB5qZzdxnwIK8mAF/h7Z/AvGITMSwsoDS3mDHe@VhedFO3wFuay8bRPfm0Y5r33XjTmDuOAopu/tE7eFJkfv294PJxKUiHC1jmmyEVuAWSNF62q7JjSHgAAVV1ugaXVEtQpbhpngvYsQB3uMMrOy1h/@IERYTEhXAuC0fYuhCORda4fLwaiDm08xC7AR23dApPvkMZPAIWTy7b0QpNTjq9xHQXBEIm3oF1L0oVEL1@VQ6vzU1M@slKKJBH29oq5aYW5LKOs7MCdnlxoE9wb3Nhlj3MJgXcdmlSyj9MUryXmEopwPncwgSeALmQz6/fBHu2FEF05ReFzfuQWf7p9wcwvp@A9MYeTe8D5R4@SQf@EwJYgjq@VT5oMDMRQdSZ06dMlZ06o2j@IC98Xggyg@qEjS7e@DWdapKNZvI2HzrvkaLQKci1MkSacFhQ3mquYf9qeXLIkG9Mb@Xj0@ONDQPhHsGrn4WH6yK6VCJOeGZ02s10XZuC8WNJfQePj9FppKVn5ujQHN/QyguDnrTMFi1AWxwy4ttq08EUAyVCs4oq3hCIk3rl2Vk9RStHS3hw@GifrZE6uvbUFKTsyskIy1mx7GUZINZL0xHYa9BRvE@8EvwgD@kAJKCJDuUlCDfJG/NGGAFhuUYXOIhtn4KlarOV3vYM3UbFHmmZLte@CxFp8nX/6CA5b0I9W56KD5nzBnYCYqVlRZUpKrjhPC5CmgbBaxPdI/2UhDcYiA2SS@4T1jNaMVvYkqh0dtpP92tb9fSaUZEZ9Lm63feG7kXrrON0z9usxwavmyNj/PYNY/kNto5qJO9yLZhaoYLHsRMMtYYU2VaWCFZkcIf0jJ7KjKmkOxHXk9lk@F1eYUky0Fi5hCcgZqiUrfUDKsSTcn6lXyvUK3YlW@7X7HoZz@r5qYqf0lIJdLgLnSewFr4gX/Pr2JX@LDrbatrnzB02xzBKCs9@MDr7gf07znCJPds0X07bjKU7uFkNz5CotnmRCO9KR8qUUP6R7tAhHg2PftN0Mc62tCzIAWA/DcKqN6L3OCndyarDge@Qj0hIQRJi76x30p3g1FGWJgwgSM2qB9nZJjiTMAlc9@GuY74bWtG4NKbhUcdkBEQNYxK3k09lGY8AYkbF0ataXfJUUze6mAm8FfMdRWPb23RHJpCUp9IkHe7U0F06@JCtoxHXN@AzoMUETIIEc4@Ob0hQfLRraOAuNAXl03kX2ugukSCIPriNm13ScSSKvw0I4Ii/w0UqVcxgCsEK5ER@1I/mDlCz3PS4HlcR8BQkr5Q7WFiEzdOrTIDTjm/CESYr0ATudy4QnRxX8IgSKBrZrhUjDJ/kwQkltAwtbB7ikqqUvKr46U2iJSLRlCBaEDiCijs3YgMnsmD089iE5jNme2avB5nmuLgzQQca6TiuSD8Vpu/VMM16mHnur1zzV6b8Ve7PMzUJpUL/PQlUigaSY5eTcFdMngRLX0urwkg2UaGmDRUkjknY8rKwnuo7DWsSuBpWJafK0GN7ykOJ@LycU/vcZ2UqTkjgoX@N@wv6zomaD3M5FfbedPr4lUQFmbQ3VmwlmaFS1bZ6O7xzCn2QzGTAJmM8OtY3kR1vlOLIpGAnIKDhND4122plAiWlBRyH2oxc3b4nq0KY2EnMZoMfOrzWsOa0kQiWKM0UIW5E5wshHfJeiYAgmEhoLGi51SDyWEQeR8BiqJUgWX5o8VoDh6LNNvEKHmN8h6@gsU9nLggXm@95h@d8xAvPDyNPI4iY7oo8H03T3ASPfXBHUaglvcgk7fEsxPlM4klkkjdM0@RHpts4y70S8okoowg4xTW8hz4C05MAWkC@i6oQPa@kn2XWpE91EKEHPXPEdnEUoXM9jFPn0VHZqofKj0gNizccDHq4qEiC3QWdeBaKO3J5XE2ZQIwso6nSIW7c4eHTaBLnxyGSyo4Q8gXu/5h4eMMO3tWN6zao8whYK06oWL4q7dpjPl8BbWY9x0@Fm2zo8UVRGMx3opngNcdbD2LaG@iGqUogi3kg5Ui8qG3evsV0OR4LQfVb0KWVJOmrQ8s42/sUl2s3tey6FkHZuVjtzarrG5ODUoCkwCOXBXE1r21IUmTp1@BLvwoCTLNH2NF/DrRpnuON0NIu9BgU0APh1DPdc7OlStIzM1zjRbhIyrjwiMemnaFr8LkbkK3wJmk87eul@WoXUBh@sX/mq8EGLYWlJVyTmiwmQ1WfWy1EYHCgpO3g4i@tR@Cpfo4PjNQ3fUDKWpJNZ4mWlkVeSHbp4zwTYAPVkkSWHkI02I5vGVAzNFEl9QAUX@WYJMbvvY/kBNIzejoe8lXnZQBPv0wwEGQgWClalgdJrIn/v@0923YaSZLP5ivShS2qJO66G5W6kYTa9EqWRyBfVtKgAgpENwKGKiywW3vO7sP@wH7Afso@7Kfsh@zGJTMrCyFLfdnpnjnT57RVVOUlMjIyMiIyIvJnwSDkwNQRuqdmJgfcb0hrBZa7P@4B940QTLNC1QzYYYLrr6s1UTs5rL8vn1YEPL89PXlXPagciL2PdISN5@CU/VW8PjkC7qIPy/lQ/AReWOUa1LToQ6L85qOofHh7WqnVxMmpqB6/PapCa9D8aflNvVqppUX1zf7R2QEdrkML4s1JXRxVj6t1KFY/SVOvqloiqidODsVx5XT/Nfws71WPqvWP1ONhtf4GO8ND@7J4Wz6tV/fPjsqn4u3Z6duTWkXgwBIH1dr@Ubl6XDnIQv/Qp6i8q7ypi9rr8tHR3EBP3r@pnAryATBGuVcBKMt7oKpiTzTOg@ppZb@OA4qe9gF5AOBRWtTeVvar@FD5UIHhlE8/pmWjtcqfzqAQfBQH5ePydzC4hP0IVmBe9s9OK8cINGCidrZXq1frZ/WK@O7k5IBwXaucvqvuV2olkTg6qRHCzmqVtMAbqahraAOwBd/hee@sViW8Vd/UYc84e4vuDA5M8ntADEBZhqoHhGD0csDRApJOTj9iq4gHmoC0eP@6Au9PEaeErTJiAR0m9utmMegQkFg3hyneVL47qn5XebNfwc8n2Mz7aq3iwIRVa1igiv4WH4F0oNMzGjXOE8DFj0CsCUW5aZpOUT0U5YN3VYRclgYKqFUltRDa9l9LnMNaziUMY0lviLYB78Y0oHTuv/rkY7LG@5aXxbYYneBo/@SgAjuyTB9lRR/OYNfZmst8ZH6DnUZ/hJ@xDDNtvznpNnqDzhBjRXU1NnDcBN00XrjhgHouLhJfuXNF2lGoQjLZaLwrN0DRrTUaTvopNWNgPFZDWrm/VsqRY8Qk8Kh5o4Hn1SvG@04MUbtL8hyT/PDwfAFLMvaX2LPNu/Edkcu1fVkNg/CxYWUiCvhU5BpPSoA1UiwjXjURdUkWCPrdk@RAFW3VfLbVQDMoOj5SoWEA/wx@in7w5mC8AO7MZq1cDpVYAqP32VfdcCeU2oD@kZkFeh3qMhv4/o9dO292hzp/tjsctm3HUXWobAh6YNd2Hqne9Ltz1TPz9QlYOlWWueMDpXeTCKOPlyXKhJyX7JhGZuM/jZD@OAoazt2ARlHqimzR0jhpL3F1dDhKC5miAqMnaJJR5jsuf6i@R20uX1wrzb1/rd/z2kJ3QEw3CxveOdW7pD@vL7kALDDKqQEo6clMF7mcUUe5k@jCt1DwGgtRcn3aq6992tcBJSDITry@2SfuxuPe1IQe@PB3p@XjvbPDQ2CdCO3a1vrmRimhs2R9SPPfj9gPJUGlJGEj2MdBTqNPxirZB8GHVoqROTsifyLgXA4LYm5yNWn0EvM1aLeMuKMSMjIcboD3rgzQA8/yEQ@WoEQazxOKXheuTEkAdmyoDo7mxpuSiO@BrEQ0IH1V@jOatSn@g23r5a@WuB6QJCBJYpR6FigXtAvie9ah8gQl5Yby7GCRrKXomLOuaRyQqYvcYzF4ln5J2jZmMWBPRVyvNO1UE4B4Pg@FUG4TA17ZbylfiDT0UrIvePNB0hs8fpT56Cg7nReE5bAGaDzUNdEeHRmd5aDPZcuXuy5M0dKS7mlHoDXfkUDR2pNmY53gw1gNBMol@gy6Yq7hks4HMt8lObh@m3LEF6ZUTMKB7ZQkxcrfQLmLhiNbKak8IPK3yi4huC2drISxdqv7SKgiH3U@CoXOGJp@FT6o/d8RJwva3wGNE1qPsGXk7HsSJqlVxhWor4SU3q06UDBOMSJsmq8@Rs3cmRNzrQcmT2mmHD4DKJCzM1MvPlKWwo69AAFI5GjYMNev9ji79kB1@tZyZHU8Dxm0bka2kHuF2irutZvZuEyT2JVWZyj4wxEO25qMDo@gqviWFbcmrXpQmeZUefEysLg5R@XxyC2TAUQveKLSa3ZKnaesvFxlig/IlEnGhtPWmY9ALL178HRuWRgZLWO8X55wKURB07sIz/1xUqryoWDv23iCRE6NXqekdZgtG9Vk3Hxkhrkm@Vn2fWznZZuMIXifbHiLG0SfW6fMelFrwn5JfiDYSeRUGKUFRHbrZAG1tK3eaujJMokUqqE/G3DOeZ@tWqpElvN3SAjNaPisOPZmAHL/acNmEsst14ZpdE3EztgsIevj3bmt4XAMoqOH4wYY072ZkxXvpdHBHwSTsUw3CPtZbywtEkroh25QbGLtnbYZTm9OoAW9EIMR2lmiDxrSjY8OoJx9ZJrZEDYQr6LRXWV07E1XCsLeib7sAE4oiyghcUdsiJ9@4lKMUJnh0ycM9gKtXJBLJvWD5w56@d0Oxz/i3o8i0KDtt3UiUaNJsgXyJFUHlJKxFfLQR8OALBowFWgB0ZgosCFN@6HCHr0pyUm6LVlRMktMNUoj@fn9aCJVzlDQUUS4sncgvo0MTCZiqSgzeercnoXiOoGySOG6e1AZo@Se8eNpYV0MNEt5xUKE@1KJjvjEfFM/fcQnaeR3Xwa4euANnmVLERQBRpkVz0/v8zmCDxPzve/547ZpEwVJpu2N0PxGqs9wQLSoTIcyfV/LCwN/BhpAK9eb5qiNhv398HrQ2B/2vW5v2PNAT8M851PmePg4o0ecsO54eBvQ9Tj0oW0Uas@iZ04fw@nU8Lc@lywZKbaC0B/ZpjtCOJ6VrzkLBFnO0cdP6P2K6Hs0n@tM11lbjyol4uGl5G5XcEoP1l0tLKrMJ/fYgGRwu3OeEhwiGlLckRFbWrpXoPm1AgaMTZERnvOAQ14M4m1AER3DxCBWwNxzPzAHgZrZgxCft6fpNuUSHGMeJf/AxwtmAptepz28WxW4yDfoEfBKFLbyRlU@RZliPkF8mD2M7uLm7ww9APArwC@sLqKWRYRALK6jkikFrK/IpKAAC3n/9YhHEycGLtbrwi7UjzXamM63Gv88ewgb5OEDQpFMl3ePKnFF2qD44P1qdgNYTmPm4KaSEimH0nKgCFIO7fzDBOs/5h5Lix8PcdlyhoxpX7ZsG0A/hKoWYAlvzZzznjVB5hTIj6@YYvGpszaHQHeRR5lxjYNtKcmFAkx6vL/isdZwDMzYmsOedPVIBeFwlHoi9h7kHQszrC3CdctxHvXzZWJzYbNcbhNq3Rk@zkqJeXjmiCaOMfIoAxpC9ZWeNZnPI3HqNnC9uY3ZI3h4CGeRf5TeVPR8t3nt46b4CR121UajlxTBjslGS/r9eQMG3niYg8g2Wb1qEMdoIMtozPjRaGoOTRpLT8cQUZ@EfQ4fbcAc9tsG3Jnz8yBS553hVOpS9SmWrBLxiXnWMSYT@NKog84XmAWOJVzNpLTAOU3P6CivkGlismD8wA2iVOxnIjsUW3CjyZqjI0rm37Eb6C1UQE4ET7umh4PO0a8RRkn0pXFHejw0ZpnCZYlbmuqWQKugUl9rSYWTw8/zxpRauYcKWOILUKFHdI83XT99VL92LFAOWuDa9Fk68ubTOBhHrAA08I/5qTFFGTjqStaMraj4QmgQa4C1AFpKt@@zuorSX2/MFI/eDXIZgQLBr238syJrYPbtjbzGNlaZtmdYxJHo5tXmiMwuV4kIin8j@uVSZFGXFFdowGeIob5bgBYwPSlBj4cClFnHpLwYoHKOoKJbwGUJLym7aeTPueA7IlUWWFs3SuQXldg228gsbAQEi8VlIkBAZllcJGoFNrqFsBglNhePJyoBArGifcY4TIWclTgO9cwxAuGRoNUc5bwg0nlJwfRxbd2JfdT0TV@388bX/PxXwI@G8DxTmP@6lY99jXVbLMarxmoCPhyz19hHQIVjAqy5wq/7jyJPzNTl2ifUUDJiUob0wx6gKnWLelv2h0DsUMy1kjFUe2bgt1K/GnwjSiy5@tcTqQuZpr/06werHFMVIDKzP2WdU6EsNuuDJLBauNPjqFDRVXn0dPoBpdIOO@Jd/fAwltS1OVN@Rjf@eD2fzyMNN80c9sqFGi1JvWEuXjrXmfT7udHt9@N3zRyxfrybvh8MXykF2ocZgTURZIfjLt/jgDBAUSydkWGqqOpPOh3zwgQ8oMS5g1njkjLXgaD9p6d9Xt7Vyf5DTcr99QoHiOO7Enrx3XosZ8pW1CkU1EaP4E@WOjwD9OCLDrph64Mqagz5snJmgm3LcXe/4AaC95DQZFEWYudL5J1svfb7/WFavB@O@23MA/Dsbr7C4aFZIc9F8ICRYncnAWWbTQv/U69vRA1jEZPUsTm1L6lbIVR6d0xxf@p3K9ORbZ3/2YJdBYa8gsNcwTTTaWF1LUfmfH9Cs0yHAPaTSt94I7tFeJovDDu9XMDRE0C0WkgvVH1iRRwyiUmcPV4akboY3CylYoChOyQKqJT0NL00kgeKa@RaF9NCB3GY5zYkTJhR5Wk1MJDs9@OKn8JO52lMkbL588T@1RkiHQHQCpTLD/CJybD/KQPL@nAuXQjLN3jnxn2@gxUaWCGReNly/3Jrl8tl8WK0siLK5T14yGREea8sDvDF3p44gN97@HvJLa6vl5jnHjhf4OWeenkn9qANMnCutK7HB/ATvrkYFYbO2jjFL3Lui3TpRcPd2S0FufPyHgbtw9P//Ou//8@//UeuLH/8J/7Yox/nf9aFstls7kXry4uluxL@Pj@4TL1onr8YXaa6JaQyZPdn48Dre4b3aLaVeCRCqt3vNR@KmtLeM72AXDXRXdKGf1wXNLCffuKnizB6HEePmBM1qu71R9ceVRfUwq6bKqeWluBpx039c4psJ/K9p99/hvfCQV5OSRMItXjvjyjX9qtVM@04cn2S3js@5sjBCyxlvhx5cHWVVNf8Zc5FNisuM@JKg4duHg0uGAeR1UwG5l8kkGp05JNDZ9dSbcBDaTJ9szmeD6Zugi7Jd8p0zpefeVJTedl@xWdo1MYKMDwsX2JfdRn3isMHcPHYy82cFzbWLzPJZDKhL0RrtIjNUW8j6ktfkKWO0Ck/A4dhjWDJwNjpgjoXcQENIjKSSboua6nF17rZA1StSWNihTuZMuR5tDfRQBKazbGFm5MpoIyFCh9dQSaCCUVhoGwwe@oZHgBA4XU7xLgE34AcjPxWrzPTLg94I0XUO@yVGDK3LDr3IuaENW5aclzPO1GDgBCUAihXDzY63yAjbwhle8TteIzqN4gb94nqSib/Fms0wdohaDTsz7p96MwmV6rgFrgTYN6Rk9UfqFA67IFrNn2Qeny5onnCIl9ehLvpoyli0MITMrwfqo85uVjg4@NfykYJ6wElHHk/XAdDQez@gB2Ihh14hA0fo@j4CIvIcAW3VElQqNSicqzul5N8YHnkOGLEJRGr8Ds6fCfyIBMk6cPyojuZJoRPY0aOrIlvdySljfBqP1SkZW5QR64ki9aKPn0DqfIGzyrxnBKQgiWzdJcYsIaZuOoPrvT4@XQzwOsIs5bqkrspsn8CcCzdjQqXp@44FsBi4yrdPIYnnPIS7GEQ9JqALBiinCZKgcjBA2No9SKV4M4kteBxICIYXy2P9Ioyx6dIyZ@OKD6f4X2Gpt2BooJYQTwgxTMxH8/uMMfBULI8@DUYDjLEcpt@2GuxAyX3/lzx4hGei9MxJQH2cEegPHg4Tj3B1MOFyi4kj4tpqqN2CE8YrIDr/1qL3h7hTJp5JYuWgSMAkCYOPTsXEZKiFjUlUANxpEgYyf9bYvBZjDD7frcXxuqkZQYGdjvnUdwp1OMiv0KATezOYRYDJdRJs2YJVxLfyjUDGa/6Box2y5HBz4toTw0GdzW@eFLX5CFRPN3WffrQ/EiBY0INKxjQh8s3HZ8h2lxxr6MkcpjKsx0nVRHNwld7oMYliMwvlinAhxqQ3GIeJ5lzwEZxDhvATueWQcSF87HmDQJG4jZ3cuJRc@jl6WKR4B7zVvSiIEUiuEvokJ4v/9/9xqayOcb4ZFh8UArpAPboyOFE59GYb3LhCrz1laAuk@MBaxxPMCMdO7LIHQVT2PR4kRqdajjmulJDlzOcIUlpRPlR4Od5ypzLuapqvFHty3jtTIpDur6owC7bkHRGjoz3kl@f8WYOu6lqlyO26OiNft2p0DIZmaUdJtTsSJTT9up1ED3oEEN3LOnJuVtEGkqHV1xejVlKFiBcxhqntuiIRpYzfYIWIIl9FcqTcFgNf3uZnnJLy7M@/ZKuWwW5wAMxWIoInpOTT/CI3sfOb6UWIB/oASNg/zUv8OE5kWDJQ2qY1nHQ3RtO7Xz6wrqw0oWNbcciPVnLYclWAJpRsuVztjS8slHqnpSVkezan3xm4eNmr932ByoXK1SVvelPDdnsOZrzv2h2F/ANtxYxcd8yeHmQgUmkFxLX9Dwae90bjx7fDOtjb1aFTYh@ngx4PmvY3ilsRngnE3055TVaboOoYd2hnhzRxJOGSF5RHkg@rZBEA87EZ4gLCxDg30MA96nHH8QHa6DBHD/bLrT0TPsmTOoVSygBO1Ff8cHJVYIv/L3BG2kb/A5o0zZuBJaP9GnummopI@AH5SBsvOUaLOr38aTHH8TOIVTqYEl4fG0010qLPhBoXqlcXx/KkP2hrzT0wZVUbMLWdeNm0g97cmT3hqXGhZXm7z4mdVJdV/3A/cdkMpzHnTEObPe8B6s00mWIUUVYkEqYasXQHxW6afxkdoyEBqmqcNqP4hrRR/6u9JW5Yel@V6kamJXDOLBRyimOM2GoG1C7lIj2WaFH/TymfCAcgBQEY3lEF08Ta74z5xhnGPOGEDPRk/vX0Nn/lpVcfkOnDRGWlF4q3TOZh0W6PkUVpEVeHmIbWi1QCt88PrzxpWYr1QlDeTVujeNkmr@7wvqI5haT/gxUKa9tU3Z5HltoMeFQ@Wsa6NRCDO3M5izQWE1hxJQkiOWMZGIExrNs6Y6j0heyDVZKoCTDPC9kK4lJj3QBe4Mm7m2eaS1G3PvkKOlNS0BUFGiqrZiq3N2ijU36@6JVL9rBFKxxmdIU2UW0gUYy6wIlXJPBo4jy7yOq8MsQxXAtwhN/@c3QFEdAHEt3icQi8tWsQ7pmmWtdRxDd40uEuOdaEJ5rY4Gg2@xj0sAIsPnmYAKVZL@thOFlUe4CW4zLwuwY7kXvWOthBTKYCxnXhjgOQ5iMMaluEqSrBPyPCY6BS92gQSdmAQGRNZfQhSg@DLFB@NbWCJmyQOSSTkL6DOWSfE1QYbPgUCdP6AkjcH@FeM9sEI9iOveC33BDIZFjWTRkAOHjux/tdQ@YpWPjW2iSBo4cGaWZPS@PRhhU8JiVOpeUqSxsAc0LR/xCAzXZSoq8B6GdJ5dMPAMQWNLAnHrQGdVekQbewIdh6IycbM6N3LBYP1SG7j@S/VvhWPkqSArQAkJeSQcon9EV0DzBUkKgQFZaoKmXQQpQrWNnFvYSiWokLhJqY5SsdvCC3KoXGoT0rNAuHYjoBtVxaFgVF1pNlYVIJBdWEzamGEVrBh0d@S00hGsrVeAY9mBpdshB2/JGbgCLAyV1kzF2ZQ5naUlI2MhkPSdjLFT0Y4hiOGLIuBjIeIs50gUmhC8J8XJLgWWipb7RQvsDF5AlotW5tFgQQfYaySGRhSYX4X0y0JhfjB2q@jX8UDDEcC7eiHBCHFXnfomgSfxchM7j8xEiJYPe3w6V/qyZeCqpynu7H6JF3os3C7wXm3vPLMihtQF3H/zba3GcLwWWRvuPWDaDr5/x/ktmCviHCZTiFUKdRAC4fRA68q7xZ5Felw3CBl@brtkv6nHS5a7dhu0YmC0FNKVBTwzJB0kYeFYOtpRg4GdtmEpJ5@4lKwQVE0GZ18xk7UgvE6SYGeqvykpAmOrIMO5n0By5F1EkJx5dDVucFwA2KPzeoawApNcWWC1ChYgrnuNPGVP5rMNpCjtyJfMIxHJDdivHIOGhQbCMtTf2wieJWNGRHDvsiwEmiQIpa54Og2xCVH@@SPYUuWz5yXJZcpls2suReLacHIFssfoL2/jrymmRgRbasTTkFi5UMuCTygEohgnqo4dxZMyXXMs8cvvlYt8/xJc/6saw/IcXX5Y1@ltxIWY5EmJaC4WYqICs1ULDG9XT5Yk9wLIdkIa8LMUe7m8Y7w/WjepvuLA/voldROVk5SF1i68XdBveDmUNTaiyQ7I/LuwIeS2v6StLru0rYd9f0Dzf0Ta8@o9t@O97G85pXGC20Ud2GmPq/zH3fw9zj/kr@1v5rXzjNzv31e8sk7CsufNWIaznorD7zebF9CB/Md1eO/lLMkzuFnPvx/A3TP4lubGV5Ed4gF@r6ten5G5yB4tt3CVnOdd14VG2Uj6EVna/121iqdkO/LO7rtrdmCV3My5V/ym5uwEPhWIRILmYVrYvplt5/N8q/ZHED/N0RQsfD7U6opw2ckPgs0DpIk9q@TCImtw3docqkoBSx@MGUtz5odEMAYzOM9PiVl7KKkBAnPzhky/v31JpM6T8SPljQspowhEXKu2D9NXjSrACdBcO/KEuaLeXoleUcELlmkApIQJaXL3MbuDR9ZXMQaEB0PkmSMxkV25QL2zqGNOb4d/d/DeWzkfxyoolwYifbcpdcUvuiv@bFKNZeD0cFBdktU@KfZiu0Bc/BAxLMOiNRn7IEn/XH/hjSmUCw0FBB6/Za@GlhP3ej@z@90o1LlrUUOOHoMGxOdxQdjQT1otvYWX1bkgr@gyrUj3j@djGmvoFjBsvbMM4GRVd0@2F15MmXUhQH8@q4QlloshhUvOQs1LkQJZr5m48dBygNP4BkBiUAHYwngxydLEbCGwYK4O592@8HwE0vEwWhtZuQDE09v9o082tgT@iEJdpp2PRNUl@v13zR97Y44x16DU/8bp@FTPxwGQE1xYqT0nxhoJrQjM1sVaWCOMgh8v7sDKcPYx4f5BS4Z@EWiEw3Jiu67EwTl0yIeLdVpaiJqCWxaEFdEV4ZzgMo/IcNa4r0M94DcrHBpPEoSF4OBiNCLg5jn9FAbEihHxBcEQ/ZafRC@qIoBmLHl6jgaPyB5Mboh19re154dWlzFnnFozrxcnjdeuVvFLeshChOE3S2FzYwi8T9r2kc8mETB2gxwGCNUMCBXlCJnRaeAOaQhAMmz9QoiXkSrAgkf6y6ptc9uRGD49o7B74XY94xW0Tk/HA23YvoAJYM9f9DLI7oygdI9XmpBtkeS1QYEUvCCb@@ubWGgFEO74q2h62YkWLOWh57I1nOQLuOrzp61Fsh9ei73/y@9J7hcCmdL68KInO8EYzb9Int5YNh0gHUBkbKWDB3k7zu4PK4VG5XjlIg5iyjsUDCkvSZW0Dufx5hb53@pipgckIq/DyzTY31pjI7SCd@hYtcgz6tybaV0yAVQNBkMU9oDeyUy5Vk34W3LAYodo@6Kb1cTilGlJZo3G5ISgTumrCUshVKz@ZxJCuAPtKIgnGEhtAHRyYitwe94Hx3Cv0IK8ADEju1giBIvvIP5FyrZ3nmYxeU6/oKQOMNZPZZSOLtd/vgeKZOp0MYtw2RWvHEylgcnj8z6zteYr4QtYqiWsX9fhSy82XdNzeJ3vifNFXUncQCpsRVx/uzdT82RMZmWYBQhzyclYhk//9XymndBcl0enboYNXL4jPrsocnWWmXuG7au1U0ILJCqHa52zoT8N9zvTphiVdoTlsz7KUXKu9D1p12/5s9jGynS@wV6@stFx31fkCXY5HmAF0BMzQr0OLTgnfdWLvdIhY7uJigBdQL2Po3ofjo9cw5egn5gfh@Z8vl1/k0qmU45RwCJ5L8X0HJ8dv0co/drJk7T8cD28kXsae7iQLs30TnOcvCfq0hUPL4SoEztn1Qzn6YG9W97pvQFqyUx6gAN2SKDAOJqW348n4shL6JqHMhZezmDhyrfjkWs6Xrkulrsd@p8S2irvA/WR3nVIIf67NLtahC7dYpNZDqOSiV9Mc1nsD2K1f14@P3NSOJ7BVd8GqSK00NXEAoRDB2PiqjNdRxUgHuApRVcjRekQw8N9KytqNj2Un5@2mSnd3D8JzxPl0QfhJRQTctidpSXFj9/6UlsYRFcxGvosveGv7rlK30lAXU7DgywFubzNiWhzE6qo@mNyQU9AWOKthGdddW1qid1hlErhuMZ93MCPKHbQW4P3x0CwvrHHpbuy5bVsj0hv1FtyWVMwWcxzIEuQKG8X8@uY3wzFsES5eSL8UAAtxUWv51AtnSyAb@q66eWkJ5GTYTd3na8tbJ729P33Yrm0c2K3m9wUrbf0QkNv@eGQCMPZusywWAY8dy1y7BARGLra83Mj7cZhba@dbIHkWNtv@5rq/lV/daq37q9vN7e3tVmdtq9ne3vQ211vNHCZ7pyrZm94ApCSLyR@77Tyt24cEs61ifrvTKRQ2Ntvr253tYn51da25td7Or611tgre6upGu7jV3G5@XWqL4EkAg1V8F/eOeQ788mHhLnGPt8vazv8B)

Policy-compliant Ordinary Shell is a shell maintened by debian that is designed to enforce debian policy. Being a posix-style shell it follows the same code path as the other shell languages and ends up on the long line. With the code from before this answer

```
a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;
```

the same path as bash is followed.

The new code

```
a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;
```

changes what we apply the `case` construct to slightly. There is a `¢` (chosen because it is a 2-byte character) appended to the case scrutinee. The new pattern that bash matches on is `0?1??`. Each `?` matches a single character. The `1` was matched explicitly because Retina does not like more than 2 consecitive `?`s.

posh gets the pattern that was previously used for bash: `0*`. The reason posh does not follow the same path as bash is because it is unaware of utf-8, so `¢` acts like 2 characters to posh.

The pattern for zsh was changed from `1` to `1?` because of the `¢`.

[Test the shells by themselves.](https://tio.run/##ZZDRaoMwFIbvfYqfVpgOJCpqs8oq7G676c3u1jFi6lZpSWQ6pmVPs0fZi7mY6oQlBHK@k4//kOSsPvQ9Zw02qOSpswp@kPAEFrEP5Op2DWCR6vK/EQHnizAYZ1OgwHEWjoawUsJ@nrE3ZwRJgm42OtMIoxByHkJk1RDFJC/FcBp2hFz@5Wl7YKL29u6BtDR5SSLvVIqP1nvjnJgJNFSdMQFLXaOsxVUDKfB4v0VXNH3Pbm2nei9F84rdrvV918pVZ0qxGb7wyeFx11rqpp0/Bc8/3xZndTEBSgEEmauFOEpTRdcXUq8eMBpxRQeiI9mOc2OujZ@p31yrH3DdwVaYTdm@bkzZVGePFOvoomb8Fw)

Because this answer made the long line longer adjustments needed to be made for the Kleins. More empty lines were added to keep Klein 010 working. The Klein 111 code on line 2 was shifted rightward by 10 spaces. There are 2 extra spaces at the end of this Klein code to keep What working.

Incident ended up being a pain, but in summary I didn't need to touch anything but the token breaker line and the token creation line.

Comment: Note: I haven't checked the non-TIO languages.

Comment: Nice to see you back. It's 1 year 7 months since your previous post.

Comment: I did not know that it has been improved. I thought it'd be stuck at 280 for longer than this!

Answer (score 5):

## 295. [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org), 13777 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                 @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 111111111111     # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMMMnnMnnnMn MMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#**#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#|9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 9
#9   
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#>   
#{   
#    
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'  WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((( \'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>  
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp         ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $ 165"6c"2:1*F 4, _._#a*een gi=[]R 8ogre;b:ui ca34  prstd
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<

#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA0UgSqgCg/iQaCbzSbv5dzuZg/Jvn1nQDS6ABSAugSq0CiABJpkx8ysPdas5LU8O6sYjbS6o1lrLVkbsfKG1xp5pd0I6euGYj/pB7QeDofCofkH43NOZhUKIAB2j6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W6YXvfnP4/gw565vWmn547YyPJGrDW0L6yhxh5O2QPT9rJGWpIw1O6wM@5bzsgrShGmM@aNzOGI9UynMzY7FouAq8Fm9rbdG1nDBPMsizWsnnsJ/mnGHOuSHTpNuwWQ2Mg9txz7jTUEvwxjj6zedf96xJpuv286LY8NhrYzIt8sY89MsLTHzXNmNrzR0GyObNcBrxxjz52e2W@0TEbBB0OLR9pmAKp5TnHmffKMPXGHngUpuE3L81x0LICjObTdx7tPP1kIr6fYJyYgNehZk4XkdZ29sK1hazGGwT4/PThYdE2zz1TXYQe3UdIzbHc8cg9Hi/CzbLdjOSYztIJmLHrmgJgjq5dP5VNzXuB3YA@hNE1RasVZyTjjfsMaAvFFEV7ao64GEU5dTnDmOr0psyYADHBsQzBrxGwsLZZNpTAk/J9YTddpzcCDkwVwAK7VH4ymTGWOK3gAvNwh8wZm01JbVs/u2yOrxXo2YOe2BTYegwJn59b00h1CwaucFQkRb2A17baNUUQOPAmZ7ZHVGHeYOx4NxoCex1q2ZzZ6EKwxZS2rbY57owRrgB8Qj9wvu5YjULKdDubjxcwFIThQBTj2mzrQxu71GKBzjuhg0h7bQY9LdMegDYuwtFoIan9GLoBk9jw/9/MJzyWD8Z4N3c7Q7AOjtiyiweeHz5jXdIdggx@G5bVgHZimOWI7Oyy6//RRlFUCMmrDhhSQtMyuGGMR35NdmL2x5bG@OYW0nRFULuZS@fkxJAjOohvRIoum08xIsUyGZaCy5ZmRTTGoEgUwQK010jr8cszIs4wOfJ@NJjCd9tDs2D2LQ@m4vTYC2kaONbLMgHcqE01w3yalsc3SeZbbZttZtg3vAisYkAhCzDC9kIVfDn4AoQAY6PBLZ3hKAVsgO0EW2B5rm327N@XQBwME32RZnW0DREBTB8hGHiAUDIQw/4ThjbpA2K55ASDVnn2O4sIKJAaWVhI@ya2tJIkslI08Sa9r9XqYKhAKSJTNs21INQeZzkDKQEcjb/iZ73Qp@4TXdgp@gOM25DgP5E0BpVJIqm34gR3EkAHyxgDhYoC8MHRwN8CcRqgQLgd@OSirXEBao0W0BekKcXUkJgoUHWkA0RgUXTrDoPAyULxpLN5smgGegMB2joFMyessn2H5bQbkKqQYkF4HZLDsdZBlOiChIzAoUh3KVAdEdGAWHYDq6SyTQnTV0@gPcdMQF0igZyBOBsxQLnoOfxAPCl6HJHVI0zAKM9YC3IwsZDKbJp4zclB42@AHxDIAVwO4xQBsjTz4Y9w8EC6PLLntE8LsDbom0gJKABkZWA0IkgWcCDaEB7OxneYsRaEb1shuSjcS1CreAoYlji89UAKANGEmwwYUGHDGPbFAAiogkOaF1dizesBFIEOaJpiRbaG2o@Tw4dgjDeUsNFOWe4ENKVX/uWQ8EhGNIbaiIK9a1nDIMCw0tl6ChIk3bnjW6zG2tTO82iCdLBCsbdPuBQhQ1TFH1A7AN@pBetN5tNtDt0/1q4/Coue6gxViF0TTJQL61L20ZqjPJJc5GPRAnoO7BYQYmz1A5tIkfYDUhXCqHCGIhPGaXRsAUlIgV@2h1STai6xD7DRI4HkUi8yo3EsjlIehZiHNBi4IVQ/jOONerwjNndVk6UqyZV0k0YU3HfNNBuLgNybQHgoQDRPacmpMEYsA0j1Do2bq1C9Zz@3PZ42Ll8Mg610bm4DepTmF0muDZLEmZh80DobNugMNdx84hpcgloTHG55D1nKd6CiAcjmE5hUyHeQEQPaIJiO7b4E@5kIULPEMIY3CjTBrTIGViVoZjdQxjskCoTRpkVDcIRNy4JUFGrbWuIlUw7RthzgIGgSPWqsKwOVKp4YGqHJDy2zxYKhdIEYh/QhaOwuILlSBJgFCDcVyPNB2PI3ZqBYCw3fcNvAYNdGgakDUWTpNyjvmPHCaaE1NIkoj3/TPe8xmzcGAgTvoJ4DWQSoPbaz7pc3egGev67FeczwcTtlkAAVg9yHUqOm228C0b6xBF0Cwfos1p02olZBLZBqp5ZIEag4WshzYNi0I41iQ7b1n32AdC6gNLXIbMCVOn2VgMKAsEClMh7fWjgmUwiw0B1MiC4AJYrRdV0P3lmt5xCOgzQQ1HhPzrA7VCKhe7ZkM6qP2AcwJGoEDLAsCR9QqhI8JSkszg0mJwv/EcqDGNIEZoa5D8aE@usvaoPuHGmtU7sxm0xqMBHu4JMVsJ6TQHB2gQkOuqgCmeV1p8wHoYnMYSBBU8jkn1IKb5yRcUdEnPctEESs6GNCmO1agwjIuUHrTW8lDiIuF1OVXGGYOg1fyChwGVBNQuyPZMB6hBEGhaDe7KAJHKGRIy4BKNhzfzj64hZMf9pnaDtJGbHSQNpKWDJwQj9UwVPj1bgPSBj2EVZlzwKBzDneANr3@EshugGSvFXbVkqYGsvAuoH3XcZdABWIGcDHIvA@VBTHjCUoNsxcwI1UXb66MUE7P@r7YfkHTORi4Q6gZXOhMUZLxIgtxl8v7KbGgiVCg3zzfokJLEcV2fjTifa5BD/pBVMWwpoI@aYKkACHGewAg81yeYghhqvUES@B3SRKfMxM0oY5joUpqDqccCGQPWmVIaMrs4RDE4AW2Dbzp8dsQjfgUmgKz1ULJiuSger@YuIYcvTdu2JPFbkYTHbUvPenCHLI29jCGoGtAJYpF215UKZE7xQx5yUl3MEpSVP6WISAF0qDIY23otEBDcACC5mTqNGPyXBWTE0wej9p5WQEDRuSqGfuaORgtYvcluCHT9M@hXpOtxDrQaqsqvFV0I0zQI6mhhzkE9QIqIWjZhUKrYbJrkB5Dpk72KDaqhfTVtUyQluW0grQEIRCXcH41noQ3bJJBDbVqmAMMTjmnRmKOgO9JCYoog0MyKdpPdCAlj/uROsMdxw4ND7AY10AUdhWo6NAAxAgZG3QOu2mP6kJLuXfP11c2ymVgNlCiQGy2lLBy74@jaCCpIbBGSohIRBu5JyOsGzEF8ouBbzg2oC0Bp5Yr7GrUHUKNI/uNBIGArJKDnOwTVpTzU/t83FosaAcdMZCMtQ50Jbs5kksSNP68NpTXUTU6R1VQ/qNIVWRejE@gbzEvuWKByiLY0PJQ6y0LVEIlHEMMBK8uJRGPKtxmDL03bfaESsBNUNm5NGoA@ueipx4IooTQCfxKe6umciBYHTgc9mz39NOyqIvcM9mwneKcQ89tmj1y3sTgsh/38eHD493jb9SXwOjZjeKiQ9LO5HPY1I4nascZJzOaUdwMw5gBflRfDxsjzoeRJeHNVHcSUpWmTWhcJj45j44/WyQJaEJIDkoBzPhbUGl4GFC6pIbpdRcaYdaJxyHJIIoflqmHzIcZGBB19Dd9fJ6N37zBwltEaiDcEbPe2OQAfMfkoePH09BzQQHzvRpt3iJSXNBCbQfHP2emcEgfn09Qa15EhlTpEMt8cnSwf1wmsF3TO7d6PZWCJL0R6FLmsKUBz/fGLUtaFgbEH5iaLK7NEEd9mnBdSuBmc47As7JlK@ADAOziaC5Te30/a14XcN9bzBu5qs2AA8hOEBb1yrA@1PxQREN4YBPXxJ7uslaUPGaNVeC0tMUKfOebrWY2a21nCuFmqzlLsxUG2iel2HZ9vXEIXueeii7aTIsUarVA/@TxLcQ9UiKhK6D6mHk9plFaXk/C3otqs6iX3IMemtuztBck8WQmK8lk1B/41Joe9TlD4fcn9iiWUvhXVyAspL67e2g88gOLgToawKBOA3bBsWUatnGioekBjzhuz@24bAvicO3QTxDUppXZ3O24zq0SMtERsxrBmQuQvzheYw6grbHfUMeRYoW7q3zWw3S8S5DSei6NRCIKEagkhde@NC9MINcs3yeH39yHRkTPplKBOUUPkCAUh8iFpmbIlRyYCglpAp@lGQxmMW7Vdt9DDU0jYKaFoAsi7s68lzqSxNSSS8MvQYlPLYXCoEKN6rjtRj0ah0OZhQMg3gAabRo/amIJeNj3HwHn85EaPsgwAn0aCwC6VVEcGjM9PgABkcSEgh8f9LAAAg20BYNMTjCRAiVDsUj1hi45qN44EtKdjSCgQg8cBwkSTtixAOng0IBgBwQuROYZ2eUZ4SmRy3yWzqHL4SC0hsXyasMe8fE7dzzEgXq7Fc4bBE8bPAxAo8yFyoxG9KGPz0dQeGTKBSh4Jqj/oORDNwEkJ41JWZQFk88GoJ7n4SAUdF1SKg6KAnyVPdjrmk7T4n1BtY8KElMH@yw6GiZ31W8mTfUNMOgauYmZ3w1PTlGhn/oEoFGGYHaKekBidIMkj9unQC@oL4WeD/2mTBpMR13Isdpksll2B5azqM9xbS@mlGgOJRrVvnRtJ3YV3djYiBajlWgCTPfBtIOm@2iKg@k@mVQyYTgNTRQjQSb0rVIMdKtFb6o@5IlSQx6YoFR4Yw9iZrVYTNcSZlUXXwO/ChQFUB5Cq/gBOFGlXEajosiVSxyGhbY5lPc95J2T5tAeCBJ8DSo7twsapIkIoLpjSz20Sqh3rqdIvzwEhdDC5iM2jJ5VU2e1s6uzVvzsJprA2ErJLIPuF4P0Yn2tM3THAxDK1UxR1WuKUk0Xa6VGOZqKbsViebUHCZmK8nFeiZuc1rEo9Dp7sbOzKJBUUKfa7A4J3iRhKEpAKMADehQtaJtiUe0qD@k3lJoSj0JcJZqAvkA5GgW6NJEIHmUatX3ORAfQufRwkBl6rOHxQhLmNN6M1fWb1qA7HYYDBD1qaEFxdGw20QaVgaYqww3bGx4/LKzntHi/TePhoOHCjjnKwsGUS2uJY3qWnJv09VuFC7Xdd0dm8nMNFKIgEdlLRjeiSVVNyox8OCTK9hPbwypsOpY79sKjCEsHNzB1cD3tjkFY@jPiCeAqeyBZza7LopsPADoLhnCxQcDRaJWPafsAWk0NfihETw@PGA6EWs6IpoptkIs4jcx7XDohwUWPP@6WzQ1ea0FqJYrDUpiQ3XHcoaUCSSCGRBO7tAxAqjAxW3xIvdpbY47Cdw@SJKXatkAiHvRck2jLxXVorHfQD8UH3RuiHFstqQfyow3iUeNlMbRayS2JJl7cYRdaCMgNSmIjKK2@8Ei63qCljSYQVYqB0jPnyTU3UCsvWcswjFwz2y76fsgVQOwuFBJqnA6or76XqoOnIgp5n3f5fP376dGjfd4vSo69IfWssI9c77utcQ84mOtEx5bTSbB94Cfbcfs2kMGP/@a8d@y6I67Bg2VVr4srxHZ/3DOpP7fY5Vobr@k23B5189ZFnYUfDz2zZ/IOpu@7@/mTw6fPnp@elLViKFDSvOivTRvHGJYny@l5GJ5PoCkUf@jX44wpb2ZlbLf8hSYoZoRHDj3GYpkJlJHvvo3ufpXC8VHhnkf3Pi4xgV6D6CGQNXAUAQsUEJed4Gy9cLzSUzfovlK/CsLpFO4SF6CEsL3SDXK/GLXbc85pcj5XUTT1Zs4ZcubLT@b0vzBKWR4I16LMhQkDylGYYEnKYjghvILpw67V82cHjkExwRFwaNt7qD451iWOzvN1IZbXRH177JCExuFz1uyaQ@9WlwTq1EDloaXIBtUTaMOSqLlIm0kmhq9KVFOgS8CnHTwuPV1Q26lntFPhk1HAGPaQT3ok@cDaZh1A7FRK/kqBVcEwpWg0CEZQCTeIQdmkKblbWQ0mWD0aL5MoSknyktWXZxMjpZ5NtvdrSY@I0Gby2dnk45TxhZxguJ5j816yY5UwuZXUIjsfY2p2QWyw@GSeZFAOY6ft9loqH9CG8geMacTaC6YRgxUlJPDBxR76i0lsnKAWi35AXIbWodyCu1B0ldsBQitXAkBQG67Y9Xni4ppVoQW70LxBzx7V2I02cutdzPxoPHQW17hwlXI4NKeeJGahy2z3@JPPq6kahyD1TRykzvPSmvhLpEAPBr0HV6KBCefSR/aIGnaaNLQxv7oGSE1oPBPQBxg8gRILEhI5QtSvretZXtrWCFQvCzH3pv0Es5Qbrd0zRyPL4bzFZwpWk5sP6YpkypT8fTE@WGQpGkQFRdNGP0CxxE5OH@0fH2vAoV4suo@DrUWodmazC/rGqkz7lAxnvsg@bkXZxxhHYZgKVCnoTNRFfGDeEjA3dCcgdRQFHWsYA0cFx0mb4ExD0xSRK1yCQLgiojkiGgXAYpYCeSJgxaX4P3d4z0ngWWRRFidKArlj94pAW1vRxo79WvOg3SA1FIJEed@Tlr@VN2MkvjZ1hfhnaPdxnge6TKQFQh6qVbYB0o1Cy6z8lr2sptRCLb7JarUSn72DiKjT03I6sTTLFPTkQ90kIAXOh6JX1l5YoOenQKMyGIvjpwPPSoJvAdnhuDG9XUvlTUNWAmTVN@DAPeVFJJcsIOMo@ssWSITQKof51QrzayFC2XpOneyFhZ@QHR@BID84xRDjuWQbZaYrio8ZB/TCHGLXucieuZ5nN3q0Mq3ds/kqj6CxLgrCCEg@ZcLJlbBiEN2wPkM9w8KYLUfki/wEJcifGhroSWHOyCGmsCskJpHSQCqy62t0kNmmwYgNZFwNyOl74/dpQT4@dgHZx2J1Y1jnIKEhpp5RdJxJst95m5/bQR/eMUheLOi86oUcjsd1Tts5d2mEODDVU5qeRT0ziN0/792O2ba9Lr3mggY48LDGKuy8fqNNryUBaKBUTMGRAw3BCQ0bitNMHtOHRuOWpDw/7TyXbMNqj50OzVegmamv7wipFvIUuN1o2KuCAhFwJYn/XRIMZCXWPEPLaLpfe3CAB5pFkJ@8TzTL@uKKBTZHd2ikRhBLfP/Lt1pA/9ul04X2Ckc2A0MdNAUsKbW9srBEVLTQa3nB8pnPcc82iTBkugtk0xxClsxeYFgOmqbtVBX0jT4OQooSB97EF@iia9iMY87nEPzv8kSWDcM7ILebq8IurODgSdGAMXQXW0QErnPZFkUiIcsLwZrwQdtQxx0F7t1I@cssGDEzL/fueDTmb1CH7yxEe4C/dXVThExlzYZuQYfUbNjWmiIfmufjlqsOzjuBWpxbEnaWe5o1UkErERNIdTQuzz7P4NDuQHPvf1cFm7WvyUv63MUVnjP2BmqD@vYtbqOK0F@TwrDH36uC2GIXQmBYTTW7R6/35EQBHRhFzJ8mcXWaGiKavUDmntmYoirU/XAuC@YiQeKUm/F4Kr1iMmowWB0f@6cUv1BYHnuiNTk9lo08JPkKOJWPzVGGxZq4O0oVmiu7b/ZUoxUyrhTmy6YybwUNZkEojnUBhUavdUyODVJz3DOHM9MaFp/h4U9OrBrnFs2GqMtNt2d7WKF7q6Smv55mlhauQaRXaM7UXkbJFnREsR1XA9NyKeA2R7jObAVbvYdM4@u7cBVdiE80dxWxmu4l/lZqEF3oDPP38kbtzVKs3kM@qb1mz4SmfGWLMDfqiKOad/Dqpe1Z9FpO2POliI6avaXu87XAH08Mjw/exdme3XM9dkLvdQTqDIEK/L2cp8O0tE1HpVH2sHmNGPInRmcFavY6bi@X7yRNeK0s9fGwjaJffN9XyAVCStfvEFK@BuQ6uviuFO3nyeH5XQVEezuGuCguZFzTyi6TVGJSZ3XuoG@AM4LLc3aQylNMLcnHEFckjHM5l@bU//4Crccq0vqtx2BKGjUoeBihkAfDaMi17F8ktcz61FrvJ5Rugd2@KxOhwj3vWdBe0ftWkTIjpX9gDD2Ven8R1e6NrbG1tK9x1PjSwi2Ca/oZ749USmRjU0wB4KwDrmcPQr0RncP3whqbarStFSYm9Nqtu7WZeaE2AAV8gL3nZ2B4hobbMTrOeDBXqnMdNOd4Pcm6A79Ku6057NDnQ@VQ/g5laU5F9yz6re008U4eriopZ1KplNBhQlM5c5Z1nal0EPdLm7/nEiaXWcqzsDh9NwwZl6dBZAmvW1opgoxVfXsKXCgkHduxRlN8v6c0bbhu70NKCoRqy0ZtDJRLWp@3rsRuqTti5TmbjV54OObRaK8at@CtjeheAn2w37yu0MNzTe9VmirOpvZxpmveun4EJzRzdVcquFUTh4X4ir3eal1SDIjoWl7bXlvruIbqNqyeyT@TXGYdvIKWXgtvXmiIWWCcNeZzxbM5/siCUBpMgVh2CzoqXatvkXWNom@2vhx7/mdloImLv1XeE8tqJif7VnNVgIENcsHB99zkdEhZGrkOdLFG5rBjYVelh8vPhOsqCexPJy4l8mHf7Fh8//k6STkbs8BlOrxnNzMuH70o8qU5TYg2G2FezRJQqc6tqed/lwJ8Mm1CuY77d4@4LVT@Jg6DvkdtX7Xu7XYT63TdrtO1unyxaWBbVTmAH0f8vIB1qAPWnW6TkWgKr4sN07Pn9nrvQ08UjVxQum57KU77uGMOt3t8ENyp2QAP8blz/M4ccdmBhpW1pmuNoV3y3JE7sFSyrQraw7Ee/l4lQ/3Z7190EGltVx8o4n9/Ufh39i07pjsaDOhTH/TGHr0oqkobHe/Sm9p8zQuSnbnDjvbG7Tc04aiJBTE06b5cxDTsUbOLG0w5Z1sdt9Hs2nch3bDMkWOfJ/1RH259r74rUsZm6iN01no2kHc41ZBfymH/E/wcrip0MYDEm7XAsEZfWTZIR3s51YF53vT4gCiaWBHHhEO1ke/4LNJW2eLrsT2aAQ0tkgpGePnMBBpW4S6WZazUrGhh9UwMi@UaK7mUlHRUyFUrBQqPvnJ8aW4BXaiKpdP8tQqhcC4Jo9CClw8ht1hURAOEdmjoFtzn@GtuNdTSRs7pjjvebYHJR@xboKLha6kI3O3gMTG4dc9lXs@9pKVqtDt6tv8vNJ4NrZnpiM@qAjB6SdwzBd86aGNja@2ES3btjAuF03uq6drwqcMHCnW8cnStZw88/mZqe@U8nVg@Bb30xclETrXp8m62KLKW1ebzI2i6S3nsuzSDC9qJ2sTZfhxeRzHPVTIu0hy3A@Je7bFZYD/sKoVm6cqk5YwRtKbqF0@tjonLux/bI1wfuoRfiJmXrWi6E/bXx6Znf30MOVvFhrgBnM9RDsM7hdG2BN4Ts2M3P50riABJQWCxuJR/5ioGOt0ui8uu7eHqqsCwZsgKWY4zMXJdHXoUS0IuDuoHe99ntZ7vqloaetnAuzuY4uaTKZnWjbnbIxp/Fd9VncpV687WInE57g/Gnvgsx4HWb4XHp/vn5O5d2gBcfQ1Cl3XN3mj5GHZoMBb0M9Fczoyr9PRv2j23w76ZTzFQ50A9Q7V9CeM8hIb7GS4aGjpLOJHSfs85URwCUbns815D2VppptqOPVo/zjMa4QIi/4uZ4W0KbopIPsa39uBDIainyyny@O5ewGyn4x0tP3DeiTseNi00BscXhDsMIlVrz1/wLFoNx7oM99/WzutAQ@k645E6HDtrW4Xc2lahyCb5XIgNWOzr@0@eK2FuoAXid@mnFnQLx15vOjOtXE2wwGS2Ayraajk6H9rvZTzip60c0@rkO@Ls4pEwTRLXj9xlPaFn06E1eu@uFAj/cf@R1cQ5xTvTfuo@cR0XWqMBCMr@scW3EM@tAlkeEaM9xk2yQJ/WncmcENgVjRDXNsyB1YDy7c1M79MWccCPzJG5oimiUUPqGQamO3nF7jWs4Zc0HBgyr@rsziP0qTWhXsdqhuF1UB01m1xZxpG6uToyN5fjDVzX4W@Stin46E/WSxVoCuj1/rPoGq79nxsxWNpzm8/q0QVfQmK1@B73VXkdWg23x99rFiw5Nl8wYA5ty0s@xi3T5JbLMBW0L2@tDNleK0NmnSbQZC9Mj2bwl3dCZiD1yQesD@qaw6aLc2TCsGbpTmif8x1iOthOwFcVNIDwE5BYZnMsTly7C61ev9Gn18quRKg0j60GbkRq0OEAI3NyuzD5mJHYGR1a7hXsJ/bFFVbqHIs9g36KcnezNdfDmqeqPaAXSeqVE@m0kkd1bKv5xsTxNJfoNRu1nvOHPCefknHFKHaoGtH4ctKkjbNLa9L8ujZQaHqWOuoOLVB@R@sGvv1TG5bMlIz7Fk4/z8/PrFRdXa9LmXWXz7QHwnVoqeLEMJAlwelhXD9Ud1dqngge/o8efi0JjXA9l/FPMgDRdffcPiA/Hjri8z4c@Mz1Rm17cgR4446EVeIEs5WFKPDhNQNNW6syAaXnjHt8XKITWpTVb1F3TKVTK1W1R@J6ZKmWc6HSuVKT2zly@T6z5C4egTiyWqrYVo1zEOpjf8tZEEx8l0ythmUjrgTVk5ywk1xGrA1dRtxLXzKAvuWO1IFH3@TAe3b4@OhUG3j68l5/F3dq3NLj5vZpG/lUaLDqS3MYmgnla9VatjdKPjzR1b3HhxoGWEFvPtehwgfn7OY@K0dExYGDZtJc2QtCX2u0XEH89PTJ4/hsVyiL7XWHbt9Swt57JycJ3PXytZOl3uHYB1A72u5kZfTDfV1XlrDvc4fmDVdJzyUprYJ0akFvFJjxU37Mw53KVdMdWK3T6cD6HBpPlODeeyafW5nJp@aF3cFayAorCUUVlRW0XEYJLduGzrY1DL6ryvPcHqC0bNInyT8rF6qg5pBODtPLtYd1awEWtRiWEmsUPiySnrrNrSNbhZrR6aIpaXp/X8R0XV9F5xOzDeXKsisLaz7AspnjnnvxHpPMlui8qIGTOgKuUu07F5lvq30Q3Ul84cC9cARjY@UCmXUAAufc0gp/aTlT01FplmudelGE2LjcbW2Qb1rvMVUVrP25wGNgl87@BevtWaxJRuWOhE@HoSh7ew8P74pwLGi5PtQnT5@zZ6bXNHt3BAxjbL0HxjPN6EsVx63wQK2VE62tIYAy1sLrDJbX5yI7MYct15lO7p6eo22v2LTTEaUBLLRRIKtnT@wlbRXfsXI8dsLnI3oJsQuebzTjW388zT/EMhYz43FFmT8nObzRiW/xMfGkbNqdA2Gvr9mG2IQDHsG@JLH1B8@ehnbfwg1zkg@iyjavxEaZYlG/wc1CclFmYiNTcPAYPzyrvBnDY38AVaae63hSPNv0d9kwOv2VXTNq/0Hg6NkU2LRkeNtjSWw/YkVI9tnhs/2T093T5yfVVO1GVsQmO46aaUJi/vbLj9MtGXIkiAHNMj9Jj7bp9SA5OpkW9QbPzxaDjC3krDyXs1me5PsYZ/PKNJNJ2m2WVG8AP1XmqZEvCAl04rD9HBPVxWbBIt@k1SOKypsctExpQkkUWWpZwgPT8yBbwn/xbGzyZek0@vKExeFnwKYd122JFD2L3f34KR7sHj5@frzPfARnrHBpt0bdciHLz8bDuqdaUE5tmyauyywqokShrMrl6EEUCBPVoqxIe/zoXDrgXgjmUwd3B4rYWyy2SfCBgtGgUJL/5VvJm6iGa7AUCBv1kYoyQXkMwE5x386f/W6Ln9vq79b3D4Af9knnpV3RktiTt2JHHlKUqttg9THwdE4qbb4LDmidHa0v0bG9wJWXqAotHsKi0LkI/Ex/cUaOnxAxiH/WI3bZ8bwb6G9c2LjzjuPQxuNn5lkZ5/8Y7lbW2C6ecQ88D6yPSADqY2fEj3gQG8IjwEdaICYSbJOQ5ScNy6GA0Z0NYOWG1bEd5jmgB1mjIvsS@Ay7xUW@/VNVK9FbUXzQ/HIDtTvq90IBb51X4yXPRsl3v/q9ZKfEwDxJPQTbLwtbG8y/ws0vk1jWt8@0maUfRsLCWsex5okHNEd6h47zd/g22xmx8OgdX/4xuw9Fc0GUxuA8Bf5WHSbP4MSqn0NBAYtBKYnttTw9a1iLdUejQTGZRDbCKQaNlhRaEz6/rwGTJ1@P8cRy1/GSuWwuoycBSfXCB0inU3Zw7xIHqChFYHzpwh6UXzWAvXZ2mIzNqlXOlXhpJjfNl2n5VYDoJoSVLruIXJVBHIgyiwF@FRENGom4rmBUlEdRPYqiqOVC60H@2Mqg3RGEkFkMiMVpZOFxhxO812E0nOLQy7jXwnOTHDd0cvGmAKTq0ASRSZElsSP0qTsClpnbC8t3hOL6Ft5S4Wywx@8toUPWkQe127VptpHJPyJZ1C8N6z0HlU4tNnrhspVfIIgTBFGUl7Fs9SU7G505tSTnTQZs@mPBsmFmdsD8z5KdFTzL8717@zSt2OJZWEgs9uDEcVF/OIDMsJiRNNJJPafMspTJLM2SyJFIBrKDe/yvITkQTSAmmpb9pTvwdvf2D7929Ozk1olRFDK6GAwkeWUnfqZqiWotMETD2ZovkocHyZMnDw/8gpghnQtJYNBJRE70dTmZdQsQ5GwB6mLWlmG4mLvVGL/gu9QW8U0b61CjSLfw0FMfkC4tAlMPaCn3YuJGfhm1stl1KM3gJUOg9/g@nFuoxpSrm2ptp3LmRKK3OWFJRXgZ0bawEoDpzNvaTCKz384cZiy4X@gUb0bwwnUxvbwuyptpPLgEdwKO3PPZkS3CIeQRyq@fDIhISUv6QVfWviOuS88OFjL4/Uf8iJPwwQ4hhHOpdRQPgTr1r1JCKTI7Fk2cCNY1vW7Pbkj@gRr8ZDD/AKPgUDB@GEZMkcTBuTzhmLhcaVKcaDSvG1NQ2hGsBFt3yJgPT5GgQqO@9mwMfdFn7oAfpEjj948s33Tsgvh9NOYTgRb72rgP4dr0ObZoLAUktwqRgZLRAFWuP4GUEGeMTeJ4ihukV8WTxkTGtX4rG5soWteatOwOyPaYkgCJ9rGu11hwDhlmms4dc6IyldmsFNZWxU9wd1WY7B90GN1khoBZNTXbaVmTWPQyqhRrkD66Ry9fXEQVeRkv0aF44pS41uLpeAH62/p6SWKORO30j55bJi0KhdtSAtwWAfNjXfxT3AsFretJdBlHGXXxk9HwMRhBjYi1@@aAxcYOP/pGY2SNncWcBJ0Volb46VkOi8epiwQf8tAYxWyTibffMdOZsliyDEyArp7Tws8be8CquqbVwEyJKGwTb1fYA40Lj5FQJOirQpQigS0jC0HHATDilUTjDA5x0F/C0z2GdIDQEm86bJ5GI12kCeWaVe6x0CUZ85qjXCgURYHOS8UCA@67LQ61JIC9Jed8XR6oK7apA82gQ6tJkZkgvy3xIpRuhCPyqdjfDuhEQife@dveGcCanUfX7A7xF9t3oK7gSR3F56cH9bySlFmwT74ztFs4JEKn1UWCTps4QhuqaXIuaLTE@2ifYDQ8AKnON@Lj@TwHVGHkBZEaCZNh8cq4GW/q@lquFxFFKUDIDDYAYjNB3QeHJ335k1NL/JYL@5//HC@lk2Ob93Ppeu8iHs2mSvDSS1mWZR9vnqnqZtXIpsoPNmumOTqTmZnMbD26sLrtxmEneSbLLM0yyeSWkXt9PtBzWy@r2utJTa7my4nz2rNz9uzZF2/rbxV5cjGVz2JsO8L2jq5lHTIQKW6zAsPf0odui1r6rOqiy1EAyiKRszO8bE7elpPJarQG/@T7Ch4erlrRKtr92tu3SnUb8jSZnkXwDid29GAeXswwlBPbtpPsbOC1WvBzu6zGbyGM8Ccej6lMOKhV7sb6kza5TXatTme8b065ux0Z4@dgJOI@@eaLFy/Q8IIe9uZYxOfQmZ9GsW5mI8xIGX/2042bxNWz@s6ffbuftDbwc4Sf7908QfOJnv14Y@Pjhw8zmQRQiZufffPZN3Z3dzOPEtln1ez9jJra2PnTP9nYMIwdI7lR8zy9Fq2en38hG6mMrP3ZT6L1Z8@@7nlYLPikmQ5GfOfhp6NOdc7ewHPeZvhP5jetkNlEc6P9hhmRNxFg68iU/uoRxmthmbSk8LPB9Mr97f/6g6PXkVGkYiRfDOE7iryO5PIRbgQD2NK@7SJSiexgsNxNZJosl8tg3P6v/w7iV74GcNBnugOvStaHlZtGKmqZolxHKjkw6IYB6f7f3/rWnQM/D6rwyJltQ75fg2eLnh0JjydSU8nkQmg9f0@/x5gz6o4sFz82/zjwYWbJgW73cTUej9c0FR6tTpGSum6c0YhNmLdowCUSOJcYd2EhtxmjCBfwexEhpgKuIsbiZuFAvMYdXiyGe7HkKb34x3mOpUhu44H1qFIBCWhUjK1KnJ6Ns2KRaF5Psu287LoPcCAreiZH2Sv2WJC4IqfyhpxIJB7U8WZPNkFKqpPIjGyMU4ZF5ugZYTMbCztFmB@NzcJ8aLh9fP78f//zH/75D@jvh/T7j3h@k9Oy28mtamxLqV3UK/xhlYpcGcpXZ2R5wFLFfDGfJF@QT7Vjpqc@uY5m09ETbBuCRwxsRoKnUsGXjwbaKhHuUuGmmZvwqQQWCjGLsjwcEwLJJ2oEWl6xmEWtXtRYxc/Qsqf6AIpJNrYLcq1iZI0jKDpdpoIrsO6mx9yIGKq9D88G/NE/PPdxzFi44HuDHLkPBV3ybAS43P0sIipFqpFq0qphUxEEerBR3MgXc0UjWWerAZVWQY9chKWItq3lNQPkhsqqG8ec3Wss7j9n8Tuf55pWF0YyuPhTVXcSkSL/CE9FYpEreGpvt6pvt@p@0lVRVeM7aq0SFxjBR6s/qMXVm5uq9jJeKon/nUpgLNETLzE0Qk5qN6q68xKAVefBRjNuNOc@QOgcOL21@ssdAB/fqe6U3T36aVRZ1NrLSnVnHoRA7sGDOArZBwCgslljSjy@qaob1ZV5AIC1GIP@ABTgzc5N5aa6c3OzswP/O/S@EV9wvdm59U@f2bMizMy/hox2Vk1WzpJngm1qYNeSFXTRkmdgqMAXwkH7I0XeQqPCnojHceAffr6Dg07oAiaHfLmdDOFIPBrapMjWVmTA9O10ZIsxq6hvGelkdvJxbh/0q2pNxW5QWa3quWxN5XLvlcaKKj9CWs/nFA0FW91t13HXl8ZeSZFr1BigZhekSHILOxYF3r8okFOBqlnTYxvcTYoAGYB1K@R@RW9eFV@9@@p/xd/Zu69@nzVe49/jN/j3eoR/p038O36Nf@z0Df4dj/DvSQP/nnn4d/oa/3Yb@Hfax7@Hr/HvyQj/nnfwT4qUQe3dvJ/qpZop/Vw/B4PNUkOW6qa6egvFbcpiqWlqylJ9V2@ByYK/FJjsVJulOizlpBxdB08wjFhqhKY2fDrw1wYoQ/izUykEnmoySKWHQpxuSaDvNbT/yplUZdFXFqinmq6ltJxdr@H509VXZ9EaHmVoFDKsMbU2zl6xiAfabCmSPDtL8n45MzIlPJz65qZe33/6qF5P0vTO2RP3aPZ/dNQPW9f@94/cJ0du34X/o6OjJ2eg4FTiD@LqA3jKlfiO@NyPVEr3z4oq1h2/mkaSO/fPKmkVzbk41DwD3eIf@MwgwreycSZFGQON4bJE2kjp8qJ0WSJDYH1RqoPZDyCCcQM4loQWAy4Q7@xFkhSQS3guLskZX2i8BE/fxA3JF5dnqJhDjyv4B3qErf8A//b/t/6fPGexak2B3s/VzU6MHgX/FOXq5upGvCtKLCYssR34QwewY5SrmwoaKdAVmKoxpabc3HA3eMeUHQ6wgmnsVCjyLCDIgUiQJqXLX7F/2C@mLR52Br360FT52dkklVJKDf@oVZwmMq9pxlIp0cUZm42qXvvTn9CBuvcVCpTNlEr6FuMWI2OUShnftp0vlfK@ZTMWK9x@Kqn7eg70jExGUUolsNz3wabAGoDNA1jfkgWolmc2qfaXIleHR3TULAiLbETBw5y5eIil6ERqvNwgKhfle/di4kK0@7vKvXtGIXV9HbgMBuCkzznV6y17WK@je/r6Wq7LNHVdyII9lb@@BhEWVdxh7CneiQEJxVSdfWxUKM2COwRCbIM305PGDIuu6Zmj0TD2xh4kZFzD6ckKHVmfSrnDs@jPvv/tb59Fy2VZlck1oyMATIVld3ZymUollwFzLg@Ukjev@O0NnXhBV242kzKnBpM3oxHhpee3FS4ho@jPIjvsfgUquIcPu7qJULGzTFaJgYxVQN@5ieAfd9YLBe7OMrlYPl4Qf@UNhVW2mPjD/mE6ntna3nqAHcTJigcFc@nKKus35SuriONsN6WmuGwIN09Z9@6lC0DTfKp0JtXrj3ZPd@v1sizL2CTCCx1JxEt4D8pgGK1SgWcLtSrmr3YWjRZLD4g59HyWRaIlEU6NQlvB8gUig2S3cWck5B1b29W/Z4939/ZPE8YONP7Gwe5ewjh5/jCiozU7s5N3Gu3H@7uPjp5DhGeP93dP9j85/Hz/@TNw99jl7PHlrXjPvmHTEvsleyF9OXxjWpZpjS2rfjkeX75mX9p23QYy9sa2bbudIfOsumVZAwjmPyX4NW3P/PJLczigh7378Xff/fi/fffb33/3299999s//NlXP/wu/H4Xft/n3@//20IW3z/76n/6nXe/9dvg@B/h90fw@@nPvvr1b/Ef2f8Yfv855PbH4hcKx38SwPrln331g5/87Ktf@RH8/pX4/ej271d/uvz3w@@s/mG8H/zO@jDf/3fw@z0Oyw/7/d/ibvi9Ff63eLhf@dG7X/v3/P9PxR8af/vdr/0xvoTln//oT//zu2//B8PI/@m/effd77/7zg/efefb777zvXff@afGu1//N3oq/Pqddz/8g7/6w9/7qz/8H@n/d@n9e@/z/@5H//wv/re/@D/@4g/F76fw@/dg@ulf/Afg2b/9gx/j/w/@4G//6Mf4/7/867/9g3/5t7/8P5PhN7jh//lX/5a///pX/9Pf/Ob3/uqn3/qbf/nTv/mNP/ir//NX/q9f/09//d/9/l//D99Gx9/46V/90S//5be/@5ff@Rd/@e2vVry/u/b91Xu4f/WP4PL@eL4PnPfJ14e6fPUL4fP3ocYsFeATYPB/9u7Xfwl4/Ne47b8HG/wHXt8LLHM@3PK9mQUg/OZCpIhVnG8Y8kY@vgUK9FahQKOHvt8ORfvZV//iJwH8X5oHOecHyX0PK@Wc3/ewOr/78bfe/eSfvvvxb7z78S@j4FYzhcRuQtXXD2pCv0vNvkc4DJh7n3AYEJL/4gt4TeI0IqfG0ca@EAG@@OILaXKdhI5P6sE1uH5BTvxh3Av8mPDy/YQ7roMMh@HGlG/cROfrcNJg1sXo8oZk0Bdfkh7Hb3wDTIDvlpRNg41QR58tPzdxKav7HhEBi3tOaBZhAv9SpsAiEGkyiU@gTwSG@ITFwethnJXLZYpcnlBQsGKcCavkIfgEh33KCB0i8TiJeh5BTB4SFIhZjh@z@lZ5wiPGEV6FIBBy6HQs64Ycz5cfQYLlySOGsBA4gX31qlzJlycVBPeWUICE4g8JJwRWjk8qb8FeJpgQT4o8eguo5MvxeCWPCWImOa0SdUpTz1LmKO9xRvlGd0bLO@8/YOxjWc@LNZgbSDAeGt/xWej7NMdyH/zP4lsiO/TvG@m3RQTfoKREKrxYMLENHl8EALiqqmkag5@qIjYPwHvCQcUpWfjE46JYAR4@PkhwgALGsohT@cbJAulHylsf/MQr7AMePjSaz8n1uD41QDGVc9s4NvpPbj3/zT9Z9ix3xUfiNN3c3JQiFTktH9E0Qxy6rsPzIr@G4Jr3D4pMzhVkdLZo/TGnsbX5jLrfW4@24K3D//4GLQuOsxIRZzOKo0NRxnPNPo7z34MHW@xjKAP6ztwkpsbTbgbHepHcO/G4bECqFTcuvQRJKEElIkDXkjYp0@RGXEokGNPKEfRjR0dHAjVyeFmW4lAHjbSOdhyXHo/HEYihaQkNaMq/Gn3JQRMGjXzFV9vEkqfRLGYYmRIo@SWGTiysk@vQeUPHt2/fAsvQ0oDiIXSrmFglYGTy5AkOfD9arzf116QbmYLE@5RMz/FLQGN0j5jCFInF2JYi8UWkHIlg0jFq5PNRNClQJlpsy180ktP5iBkOmEmhq6yxl5PPKnOe0mnRQAEm7RdTyODxw0fHhydFxjMgyBkLgCglGu0TeBcgocHgxU5EzILLeD2AK5/guzhDNmYUQHYqkYoUaVqoWftPSXridR66E@h8JmQ5oedw5E@hoT8mfcMtFstv9cy2BF@yjxmeVsO3tkF9xlXD2s4Oz0blSqXRUjRCYeSkSkWsJmG6VDnZP4UIp0dMN1Iag67pVWbbyGQzWSOdy2W3DT2TK2Ry2Xwa2o9cKmsYeiGTKeQL2zdS5Qs20RBXFcy9cs9yOqPuJq7hkM9Scogcm9VUAv@MdBreADGhZ7drGxu9KxURPKMivMLFODdgvVKhhrCP4GHSRxL7CJzggTRwhQ0Ty5sOj0pijQluIo/xhSaynoWKqEhnUOgcnDQIP6U52wD4HrqqoZ8U2fjmN0esUoEuonp4IEVAyHWZv@hCtVtaV6M7vVvjoUW@HcZa9uc2XiChtWxv0DOnUKlSmhS5ublpA6TDA5yaIyuP0cL3TZNcGmC@mZjS///8Az87/KCVCq6kd81WGTft0PEOUOOUq1a55TbpYplSu1yt0T1BpZbWcFtTzRtNQWyJoixHGz23eR71PW28uQ/3oZWTZlKr14EXRm69Xi5Hk8nofWM7W9xIDpManSvFYm2osPeN3DY4njncNdYGlyy6vJx3KhRbmo/UE2BciGcUjVz2ZkectlaBPCFqFUTkSuBXdFzHusE18EWzDZLzqskXOhVlI5uXS9XSzL6dk0u1mwd9q2Wb7CyF656vlkbM5eQbPxwkbUGVo201sT7eboK7J4qps5SyInIKIgPKhKm0Iw54qdDCnSoIjhpe8Fyt7fhHv1QkJhmGaqTVtK7qafy/w2Dg//uHN@DfwDfEShvSKR7r8xSKGwSkwx7jGbQjl526Ll039NBqrgix1zVphdLe0PW8v0eYh6Zzzr0e2fzMkcDrUxPPGff69qi7IsTzQR@3hFnDfzQI@/0GIIg8yAM8hNew57rLAmyz589W5PJJcMoXEIMf8wXBjw8/@fQ09D3d3937VMqxh0dPHy18siJQlj3ePzgNrNvc14@aDUB8Y//x40Wr@ESwKcUxvA2W3fYNuoRLHO9B1@OeMGZzM2MKjS/47hvbC5bc8W1WRenU35JD9cNuWKzJd@lNpAnfaC6UEX27IEkD5riXbDvFWm6vZ@JVa@0NcOyauNXAwia7RzcCYtKX7rDXgipmbUhPcFdDQcf7pBAJ6VMA0h83aVenPZLw2JIWXoKGY8YNvMd5jBcNrnCEDzqhcWh3uiM2unT9AFLDNBn8PvSB@Fb4Ga13GPE0yO2WT@92cCkimSMzki8Bw5ZazvjePf3ZEJi7kk8Vi2epG@Cu8sPz4sCajDxr4O1PgNPYmD0H3jeHKCK7m0nsxbJN0Buzcq4pG0V964BlEqyu1SPmFtK@Y4P0P2Z5KF@r1CiObSjJdAbbe1DWpL/@zd9Fxt1KgoyK6LKMKyw3dEkj9c4o5LP5QtrIJ/KFfCYLaWQTupEAVXe7ABpOSs/ruXy2oCfymUI6AwoT@GYL21KEr2NJbhFI@BYBrNPEe492SEPUuqAK8pkD9iZmKixiBvYxky2II@NNt9DC4BauLbssGxkGXXvQ5AGiyZoscnCwlzo4kOWHaMFp0r2ULLfQks2nUtsPZdkinz1Q6gxZdnmcPG4Sl0fckko93JPlMQeA56vJchct@zkcMJBlGy17uwcHmE4bLQbGh2Dn3Idber5lG4I5aEmnacRBll8H4CDcLk8oQ5juowXTRJ8D7rMHfrL8iY9PKgUQjnk4DuFTP6@7u7J8yC27u@izRxnPclQ/Q8suPbI8BAtUClnugKGDTZ0sN8CIVUOWm2BqTk1ww1um8BAuZ2TK8pQTCEkkyxMKbTbPZbnuu2Myn376qdkdtawOf6ZD/m0CauBjT8b7B41PPml0Oo3hdHf/k2P02dv71GxPx8NGpyGiNerwuBAHfM7708UHcDys183eUp/PwMdZ8KlP6xbiVjdfA07i6WAi/foe@OyBz7JJFw4Nnj4EbeDzsA/fh2aDfPyHfOg7aTTkEjIq7qOnqyKhztCtjYm@2Ry6JbRPyhuMRWPRxLSaS9VK5MH6oJ6lSjd0R2SMrubGnicoUlfT6qScqpUn5W2Dz9q3Y/LZxMjacmKjf18vgO5l3teNTHxSxK2cbjvKoqp@P6bf23oTewo6VjpTlM/u31flql67b@j5Ym775dZYlpUivu@nt4tvoLMVha4evpTqdu0@KHSzKNvbcTNpFLe3ldINkGMETWdjPLLq9Vjs0jLPFQXRxT4JZIHfUDmlfNqldmySmJQ5VmyqlCZlvcTPh2GpW7BaeBjZuDlyhxxiB8BN7qeKdAemrBfyMqSfTMYUBSQTCRH4zpbEvPj66fnp6Rcgs6C3J/pKz/jFaiVh/eTTPQ26T8KGh4hpB6gfu0NtDwXLnA8/48p3OgV5q30K7R/oqr4bLq4fuj1tfwI9WFSyfQ//aBhNHOihnX46B@cEOoo8ZdybWKLt7k7TYnjGmt1iZrkCJrPFYoQVM5VLannrlUq5Xu7zaywrQazP@D3gMzCHHsc92DFJ0a9wwbnwqJdTN7PwT8d99pAHomt5/Wj18kNoylMlB88WtdC6ySaRiVRp4fFrD8sPr8ZFHM@4KVllC6/7lCO4n/m@Ux47ntm2nllD3CB8eLQJzQsuU4eOgcWUTXZGl4PuoSZ@o1aGzJnDJWaqlQaOKsw5hqxIPlDLv@4T5oo2T@Bk5w10a2IvldJrsA03WaylPYSeSKbUij1kdQWcUq/ar9rMYLlMie5MihEsM0EUpIs3lXLlM1BwOODzYhGQEZxwDkAxJYBrt8jDVAb2TalTrmLga3ztqLJcU9XqdU2qqOoLqQJVtzSNmGVv3KBDOlmqoRupXGkCbvp2ptRljXLj5aQ0LA@gZ81KPSh9MZzA94SYJaAhUArgvLlmsXe/9C1lR82WuWOJgF33QImAxr08mRVVulw1MrmEkcvg6EMuDT89YaQNXNqdMFKFhKFDaw2tOMSH3zbYM/CDMNCYGzqOUcR6MZkxOZGapDQ9oVt6AoieemW3XimJ8xhoI0Q0JTFy9/HCUXBARgLmJSt8TSVubPViLZeZOyqxMkiTEuXTTHTZwIYXwjm2zB4Pr6gsvRXrbcYw0ObpeLBfrRWL@5PB18Erpr6@n4tvp@JvFKUUAxGqlD3rtVQpSRUUPkSFwQawthh6Yd64X01tQL6v1Lp6A8U92tS3jWJ1vFlVdchg6rqzI1fkGhTYDRO6DsoUru7MFJaZWx01ary5l@kFoyRpNCVOqekxo7BqZ4Ei4UHaAqA0EPIQictiZ7K/RSoWjW4b0agSLeFg6oYshtVACPJLgEEaR@/p92VQseSiXDAwwEyW0i6YVFjLupGwr8wyBSlyJd1c3exAlzNJy6NADWQbZFK1ygMpUmQMVL0zcc5CcoOxD111Fd@pvOTfM1wbCXAlOsSnymq0EMKysZ/EPscdf/dZFBAzh/2qYaRrVWMbmkAQq35Qw9BLOFQcwcWXWgUo710BfjvxCq6V/4xNp2Zc9Sl7j7FOfFOiTEcWyb5b3u0c75Z82x4Oep1JsiyXonLkKhqJ3sBfhK/PN4L1@Sw0x@avMWxaQKK3EZIYbO/KH1Mp4jnzMbPI5UO1prx9aveu8mmVd/tBZN3cRDaTVCj@oufPXhlZKCbH9R2g@zOCNgEauGwWR/AiyVcD75tGPv3k8Mh5NDyw/JH@TF2uRFhKV3FBcakoXLN8/F8u5A3ZOE9E2INIKcLO1ahepIXSbHBSeLn9Mv/yyfOj50cHUuRs43rDxcFd5lOGvXW@9nUIGE1nooydlSOTcqYklr9UKqq@Y7D70A4wvMy5refU1HWFc3CFPHIG@Lz7pR9lJjt5sBug4xahFLNxo1LRtwymRAbvvvp93L1@tf/57mMW9cwp@7s/@Ymx/Xd/8q9pUUn0puTR6OF2BEKiUc9tR66uBldXN/Bwv2ykFuFIZbYVMPM1TXpkNmlSTJrm1nY8YzxwSkkRVt/WlYinRsRA@nY24l0LLyOVB6@9I26Toa@kRPaP7ayhP9hBltCXsYTlFYAf8k9eXTMGlmal1enYBpmSSVZ8q7Kdt@oOe4vjzm/VDfaqXMGpTR03eviDq1uVSgWhsGglntyKMiMLftWbUi3OaHAWeoEvrS1n62yenc82WKHggLvlbXnCacuD7tyWQ3/WlueB1bdZW196TMZ5gmSy1aKJtR2LZStQ8ltJQOdMefdLv24Yub/7k1@9rl/Xv4B2oVAo5HQj8nP95z@HAGu2GPvdMhqHxr3AaAi6c2zFlaNaE3qSeA9tm/HwfucOu3MMVAa740BHHW3SBepBVDJ1fm5NK0bBtnAHYoK0ajpVQilJUqB9ktY87DQTBINt4aHPUCulK@kj9IJmlZVBVkofzUAxvC6@13Obda83Hg5oMXKM4um1BLsHUSCFj/Cgnw1xqzsJXBVkVHLrdlSOskdUI42I9S3Pw2ODoAmRPoIoj4Hh6SYpNjBxky@GtB2Q8BoGITzJo1WFtGuQdo9HqJNrjHLPAyQYx45HckCzlj4CrYCoYIO2wOwdCFACkfIREADyEBOA7RrbYWmFXdnxeGl2JtENLk7ll7mLXX8SRkNoLdzQ6kcuYThwAo0eL4tAvhAlDKpZyNEHwmHwecMy9AkwOtlQ3aIdwO8NCmDRaRsxyhq7d2@GVblstxRGOUL45/YAh6OoHJzluAIwvzf1casoJ5gTj2NhfzTPdkDxOKELXKfyY55KoahMRuuNJMH/ezMtcuRCUZFHCTMgyovXiiaQDCIj2XkZNtlOmenGtsIC5JuAe5OQorOIgi7i2eRjzfjC97wBDH8e8Q9clfD69tAQn@DbxR2mDBq8MZ52ieeMcGEgdobyk0RQih2O/NhBLMiK3aPQbXsIHRiat/SPJYqldQWjzY5xIjxouamRYbjuM6vgh2JhaAZfEw/gEels0Lh804UC9QauQyf20OkCuKQWOAJklDj4hKM9di7xdGRRNhQ5jJFHh54g5yPGdAIRXThFcXFysTGEXq5PmwSzOhpr9lvMKLAYMRod0OIE4BSKRAg3LDwra@g2elYfUDqxLIaH1njFZLIDKtG4QafUPLGBr7oHNjQljpcUd3slL@1zO3mKpzuqbhvUZ7HnN4JaFFY/Po8pToTpue4569nnFh@5jc3tmPaYkUuAxpoAys5@QNgiDhIb6QRLgXeCh4LfNny2uTGfCMXdiE2V29@0vhGrY4leU5tkD/HergvTCdGXnmtJdIG9qeefuUAnB4BdC0SuJXZbl6O40TM4RkASp0eU6eACDUfvBzHobvqnLqARFHHrAkKouoRtDAjNpr9/GWsx5PYjagCo7kHNwgOYRsMi7roHTIatWBOqnhDwDvuYpQ2J7kuhIzHE8RUAA4u@PA8d/CAq5sMbtaBgNL7NBeQK1M5@C/xwu6dgP4zvczea6XCsGXuzDQEOGx1Kq8x4tfAt2ZAFawfyM2V9AzxzgOESTDZichzAxmVF5qCD@IvRObdLJEuK7DakBEMIgtQAhVQF/2I/FjrGWAKPh6bHD/ETRzVdXl5qdGbYeGhrlodH@3p4W2Fy0LFBG3aTI6s/EJeo2HitloA7M6n8RG@8w/L@hG6PLNyb8q8ktb2yWHQQi7a9KDaOF3hybadPZ43gIR8eMdSBTadeN2M0p@0J/jNqiSuf/4rIf2o@eoNAGEMwk8Q00UwAsESjeZ5oX7ZKwuOCKiQAh1K0fEc8pm/oW/qeb7IH7SCEO6IF7L690Ttvuj0XdRKZD63OkuY59ENOfauwD@wJRHKsS7Y7HJrTGPkrGBoZODYltYdNodknHzBCM8Ou@KFx9qQ6rc1FnwTRoVELJpCHeJCIdLUeKD9BEP0n3H8C/hPuP5kl6idbndS4SoZON5gd5Ho8f8oPiWCmfpgbftrezIcgg2LNdA4CQ07n3G7g1yxTbJ/e3AblWPYZA3hiAAS3Ysnqy7PqWc3xrMutWjzZAWaXiRBQ4gC6WiOaXrYCM1K/d9EbuN6ck4PHjkGrJPBGp2ZXcAPnFcxjUEDEGJxeNp4U1elrfAyIKwQiwwAB9TDwRNVgdxSzlVJwDiV5AuNU5RmNOWJVgUyNtC/hJdxAXeKk54QNA6qFAKF7kCVAE3yYX3P4Qe6@dHgxxJts/bAqnT3dxxNLorUoUHKhqnBZU6JCCmGlqj6aQHZUV8uLWfH9oSiqC16hbN6I8g@jv/HB6LehXizHnhiWNxglKVxVrIkFarUlqgtRlVXKoXIFDJJbZs8aQsu1z/VT0VpDMltJv5vB08EseJd4b10sVPhNhZcPbSmSHbkYsMK0XIYsTsu8WvJ64ZOUEzyI5oloU58RRHwuQABGamk0S0SbhKNNymUuONhkRbTLEJITQnLCo/DQkxVI1kQ06D0FF55i8dRAO8VFXzLA03kzCmrQQGZ4eR1OUn@JpynhLKZIcyZziAsED6GKjXzWrC1NvRpCOiS0FgAgI94C0OJ3whSlRYGnq4EtkFGclL6M4jbBBlxWAIORCC7xEwdjAZNRHxgUfjlO7QDUXTlelWQdF5zRX4r/5ITv6P/0246p@ZD6vGMqsfD3j@JYQ8qGKmhI@9BTGRTI2JN5Lq75ndM5Inh9WtcFra5x6bLYEmUb3JP@DcHJRs9tJPsmLgzBmyKCe4MVv/@A0yHswcAdmSM3kynyTpNNbLcsfd5nsDuOC12T8EmjoOu1XMtzoiMo1KbbcWzPSuBNxVxlt2iZAj/sWArrycLoepIkRh95NxZBc75CVbdex7ur6vWYZ/XaSjFY3olWDdkzGpWw/wumUHwQTwLo0SDm4h3sI@VumHgoroh2ajfPY0cD4RmFRHYZyLAm6P/g2wUNhnnurOdIx3OiKt0Yxejk6a7bdzug9Y09TcLYC@APZ7ARIXMwIFwSzMQubTF0MjLVklgzYSoi6mcfHJV9ZsRMJYhvzAOYI0aCDRdpjJQdLkmuvjI5Hs1P7@TD8T0J43uyHl/qhS/izLvmZe75YUmnYzMIEHCGRvpuNDDrILdat9CZQyVwRr2KR3hvFFu08KqFmO5C0F0RXGsDfyQCmwe2APHPV9F/fQH60ffft/hMvNDvZArypo/rAWN02LnnT2zGIPihokiRJckFrP3oPdOCsHgdwwGqEKDGkuBy8GRBqJgD6HZ7wXnXPuA7eB7XT93ie1pUVeaeS3AaXiTYubG6iB7VW1bPnFqtmAiZCMH1c3wMHTaSV@@XcRR0JPRc3teLQdulBL7QjCPReaDiCpYxExeKspqteBA74B4aKScMD1fTD/1viWYc4ivz0WroB0SjeMqVc2Hj8OdgOpjyw2t7dMK2L0d5@8NLEjdO300QoIM4diMxS1ZZJz6PY0GW3qNFCMJq81nGsyV9iHhs4@0y/DAS3Z1TKNxQpLJfytL8QezLS9xeV@IhrvB5kk8bvR9L3sV0781zIVbjwGYibO/DmpBbkHE1RrMZC0PkLmtLzHVuyQR0o3E6Z0WrUl8iUIOYJOlGNnW3Sb9QJOwZH8IXB5w@hy8C7FijOmcoP284piUuj2Dk0zcHIa1FuICSDlBCVOQkF2iEQkm@GYJf3QRpNlem2byVZnMuzaAGzCcZCiQ155IUpYDFs64IelZ7tEI6oxf2neGzTmzD47jmEEcrrqJ2tGgnWPQiWgSBHLWixf0YCOVoK1p8RAYvWjwhw3m0@BkYZnUreh0t@tUCAwzBSoYH6C5EONqb0eJeTLmRRua55fnpatFiUKYQ5j63EkWAFJhv0Bpxis1xRTZHQwsaNlIqEww5xktg94nGYRL0S8E/v1qBjmhHTxzj3KLALM70uUYj1GLwdKDZ8I8AXlKTi6I13z86oNVMQRBMJg59vHAcAg9qeCQ6L4w4YuhLMxrwBQRRbhaXY8RCLdl7oiNSBw6lQp5Pn6inkT7QipF/FQLXZonQfRoivl9e8yB4Ab4fnhh5FZ630PGTI4xwTlZZghYS9VV0TaawrOdxEaUfLiEa654PhDdi@kF4KRHYkEwHHY4m5zCxgTuYZxLyxSXxdjgODcrxSoncuxCNpIKomSu8yVnkDAVDuPIr67ITioeozYkg9KymaryWBe0CyWL0msm6kKbKKx@gEJI5UMOt5jndVfJIGCkcFzcJaitWNUN@XJ4kSa55MQmRNTwBZmyOeOpB53Ufz4X5sO6rH3OCYy0xBBCKGaTC5av7Afq7y/V3X6H2ibCQwDLFenlTelu9XtvKLmDemyV7uwDRM8EeKUuVoyCFGcmhdxDSzNfx2i0VH5d8cCWfJxpAX9D2fbIFfYI76LbYt@CwUEsYXsw7nhvgeG6sJtRtjaR3oflKi4YpCTg84wGms6ytx5VnfFkRow@Nb5u9Dy7g4XwBhwsP4VEGhgsk57V8OHZolcusboPY5i4oUvUi44KcpkuDYp45grinqdtg2hYcjurHj46ePv4GNLrb29uKaKOnM/yw1uJYa9COc8i0eDpoD5Z0W4wEXj@Ak904HE@3z26cOfItWcKFNSgDJqTis5@o44qQZSF5vlB3IR4PG6KogHU@qwbmnFRCVcfEJtsWdB0BQaxRbMsUQHz1FuidoN6aQgft1@t442i9Ts1XvY6Ll@p10Yph0fgz4srPIxvJsTekG8/4LRGXkkS71tmjI/bi091TdvrpPjt4vvcZ@8bRc/Zi9@kp7mh@9vzh48M9Br/9pyf7TJpbG4k36mCHEuj6yGpaeJ0ZHp@VYQR5zx1MudyJ7Snc/cTss0/dpoXTVDue2X/Q5RbNsUYVHmsfuqNTHMO06dakvj3C9RZ05Q90Y1G5adGWO1zrzyBsA/q0fezz9t2W3bYhrIR934Ftef7OL9azoQRB3vq7QxNcScLbfWjpEN3DhSuwLiG6CeFx7gbAmHz9FV3qans8gtXSmCBc8HwwBU/3j5@csN2nj9je0dNHh6eHR09P2MHRMViffePw6SdAz8OT0@PDh8/RiwI@OXp0eHC4t0sOHIGUxnDX@pdjb7QWBQ2DE1Wa5zjzTXf3Brb5UW/U4NmlSZsPPRYdOyh9bLNnv7Fa0ZI09lB9wQ2PNFXAYpu7x598Dm0@s17jDKc/FUzrD@TnHt0ytZliO5QaVJYK1LeSqK7Q7Km6QvMR/SnDQ@etEm1Qj5E5wXzgtIinZVtM3sM1Kjj2zfexU132QUNCGwAbQfkLVsqMLouIRhM7BLICqTV7Lh6dx1PjiwiFBaM@8JealCSimFgrg0Bxr8Khg@NBeilwAL4HB0MkOxryACwdOPAALMMdUBU9xLUjLCtCjEdHYxTPLMcdvuwPDmhamG0HDg9N6sXmBU683KhITRZctoO7@nt0JQgf5aGrykyvadsUxaPweF1Gr8crhsUvagKZyKcSaW0bhJRB2LRxqkEse@P3FKIvcAOuEzLbI4/FyorGTnFxkOXY/DKWTs90@BKo2dId4j2Wx5NeymKBrR1cYkK7PwYuMSBeoDSPRxDvkdAKrfeNBzEf3krRFGsk6SIxfwnaXQg8vIXALwIGAKlzPZ0mtVS0xxTBuG3ByjHPBY7Ecdu34fDAzq1x05qLIFZtxb6037xRBJETc/0kf50iYQdF9MYaglpJU5ltdwh1nMQqXfuAUrDZdQcjm5dhbD4HNONEzRyExoYNUntVrsylhnRYTNFxnVCiDeDiFak2gCnfJ1XieD53Hoiv2R2AwPnQCPN1d4iO2cC7a2dzZwmcRLq0cPgFFGGaK8fBz@mIMOH6pzSTHW8ZXiOWL1cePTxT375K4F1iXCzw6/v8RYf4A8bEtKB60DwfLVgcot4lapp/B4w3bmBssQZPSEus5T4w6Ad2bejXPaiXAj@@3Pi2O26OWXQnx@vrMo@lomQSNzp63dhMuiVY1U8yQXFqTCwBCclOQBZkfcx3SRDMQF4/wG0wWAoloIiDcgT77Qs3rAgR4ueuMW6DZBEX3YniDuArrEIrKmb3fuK2lnB5JF/GHpbjFSU5W1DCQuSM@SI64UPWFSW0LIXaq1vgHq0HB/L7/cHl12LHm4cPgvZoLbQPwk2Nr4bFm6UQrPcH@3YNWN64/UJgIe@J1YB5I3kbWsDpAXMmNiPBatr1Kb66VXZU9wAMtr04ghIADaU2dmiK2j@oNsYjKGEwM4Xo5PTR/vExk3n/BOKC3MMuQ0uIQYS9wZ7NVtvaDgk7LVCags5yoDz5LnMr2vxnXWVeSrwVokLoIAlBj0BYzG64bdsTLvVEy0IqBK2@J4HoU24euytfBnlVAfgG@oCA7KzQQhmUlmYzwhsf2wsvAhd0S3DdOLyGn1ZY87Ybr48bTsOAwmuCzA7uLFlefi@4flz00@EKlvV6TBlugSYN7Q30E07wrnoIqGnzJbimWPwixUX2XMGO@LTDhV@peQ37789QxEhcCee6cEisC@VYoMb1401fzaEFidgMmLjSU3jyFc3g4Yt4ctkJF6gya/Ri800QKJl4odiDMFdA9NpNKbjhOjZrJ8uBQh6ua5uETdXHsoajswJ2aXWgj3EtdG5RPCwmBdJ2bVLqP0xSvJWYS8mn@dLM@J4AOZfNpu@CvZgLP7r694XN25BF@TnqD6B/PwPpTT0a3gfOPXya8P1nDLCGdHxpvV9hFiKCqrOkTZnLOzVGYfwAFz4uBMjgkdF4R9tiqgqbLOC2HDpvkcLQKcitPISqcJBRXmtuUf9mfXIokO9Mb@PD0@OVDQPh0sEbXJX/xB161mxXXuiUlZAT7lydd7OGQ4eC8f1MfYQSo21Mazfb0W47vuCV5wo9ab4tnJO22J3El90m/LEGSoSGFzW8lhFH90qLw3uqXgpn9eDw8T7bonPw2nNjkfJQVkKyZ8N21iFAMpjGJbD5oD18H3tF@AEOCR8kkIl288WINsqduBFFQGuu0l0dYlmokK36Yum3vabp4JEfCfljj8mJexCRRmH3jw6UZSPrqdJcfEDOGzgxiJWQVU2mqOCGA7oIaR4EL010DzVYuFPDXym55jJtM6nnU7mCRLlzEqNEv1qoJbaaZZlB42s6fW88vGydd9zuRZv12ODLxqQ5ffOasWyGpSEt4x4/NVXPlZN0fuQ2vPOskCLOFQjepyvNzmTGNDrlFCeW2awfXtpgChmo01zEHRILXMq2@j4X4ha7UblfzdXKTjlV6ledWgk3@Y3i5VFcj8fQ4R60oiBj@Mx8dVTDNjU86mo5FwzvdaSLuMTWEEZbQ8DliTm03ce7Tz@ZG41DBQCHwMRabxpQ51cyfoSr2XDvieZYlzExTJZgyLESKkjSR7QrSMcN7TSejMMxLRswg1JJgDbrTeg9VaSPUtp4MHLJRySkImuxa/ta@sjfxpSiEQUIUrVrPjo7BGcWJoYTQ9x1yldRqzpX13TcO6mEQFQxJolD@UyWcU8hIir2clVrkqdZZrOLSOAdpNcUje3s0I2kwGqeRqN4uJTDHNKGiVQNjTgBAp8BzTZgEqS5e7TtQ4Lso11HA3ehMaoR7ZOhBfISaYrog8u/2RXtb6L4O0AATviPuM6liSFOoXmBIsn3DtLgAh5ENt/xx2kG3FbJC@UjzCzC5umVZ8BppTjRCJMVZAL3jy6RnJxW8IgcqDrZbmUjCK/w4EQSmqcWNg9pSUVKXhX89GbRYqFoqh/NDxwixUd3UgNHuqB79MSCajVle1avB0hzWnw0IwcaaX@vSD8epO9VMc1agDz3V2/5q3P@GvfnSM1CadDAzwIVw4HkyNUs3A2TZ8ESt9IqM1JeNCjppgYqySxs6f8t7tm200iSfHZ9RRpki5KAAmzJshDYCCGbXl08gCzrSDJdggLVNgKaQhK0rT2z@7A/MPM@nzC/Mv8wT/sVs3HJzMoqIVt9fM60HkRVZWZkZGRE3uKS38obZKejth9mLuuuZK7UCVuRhIyR8nlB73PK00gZzeA6/ZTTJX8XZM9rLCN530brx19LdpBHxrPS1iTGpdmhP3jDk5ZOQTZLADWF4OLY38R2LJTSB1MOJ7CCw3N@EttyKYSymlcjDslMorz1NpGVi4w3qTga7MV4T7AWyIhBJapzlQg3I4dFqIeSnxogCCYymlCSW1aF57Lw3ACLuZ6qatkL8p6AQ9PiIl5Cv8iv@E8JexQ5lS@5OPEJYz7jxrN3c5RANOg@TSwmU3Q0QXcR/igb9Y1ZJKx7Hoe4eJA4ME6BdZ0e@2D38Bj8qR4nzIFCjRT36K5TJKXDDHnFvg91ISbeWf9yVqx3LqyxxwNvJiq4zXDJC8uKOLhjwNkAozpRIJrgejweoNaRFny35EItQ4QU1lDdEkI0ZvasVUfLHs6fxifpkA6FsuIQId@igUiYEFz38QJ2VOxgLCcYWvHExZ9mrcpwzgcaIDMvCuxm7onrgLWmsNvvm0hwz7H0IKWDsdvxshas0QJY/Vjc1B7LtzxPR78RjC4GU9qmZf3p2u/8Un2H@txX@dyLvEGyG6kOzmVfvAwdrIBIKqGQg2XsWv6lZRm64Q7rhjMIMC32cKL/CLzp3XjDoWdVYMagjAEsWgNvcuN1s5bV8LQSGOEiK6NmEv2wR9eTDh/uwKLLBWZEL@Egzeow4DD8xfmZ1cUd0pWlLVRahdpm6Oobv4sEVB4nvRFqh0lhgWECmB5Y6MqbAlFWbBFFiXTPEhdau1zhQRRQA@OcGLoJTYbhaOp3oGfoJMsaAChWg4SVDbsxTKC@zsBF5@DsIgTQPSakgEJAqZK@hYMllea/CwchG6Z07K7qGQdGvxHJCoi7N/Fh9A0JTL1CxQzcoYNb7@tN0TzcbR1XGjUBzx8ahx/rO7UdsX1COm5UlFNEW/H@cA9GF61NZ635IXxIVJpQMkEJVuXgRNQ@fWjUmk1x2BD1/Q97dYAG4BuVg1a91kyL@kF172iHtO8AQRwctsRefb/egmytwzTVqopZYTlxuCv2a43qe3itbNf36q0TqnG33jrAylCrXxEfKo1WvXq0V2mID0eND4fNmsCGWTv1ZnWvUt@v7WShfqhT1D7WDlqi@b6ytxdr6OHxQa0hyEjAaOV2DbCsbMMWFmuidu7UG7VqCxsUPlWBeIDgXlo0P9SqdXyofapBcyqNk7QE2qz96QgyQaLYqexX3kHjrNR3qAL9Uj1q1PYRaaBE82i72aq3jlo18e7wcIdo3aw1PtartWZRWHuHTSLYUbOWFnixGFUNMIBakA7P20fNOtGtftCCOePoA9o72NDJx0AYwLICRXeIwGgGga0FIh02ThAq0oE6IC2O39fgewNpStSqIBXQoqLaMrNBhUDEltlMcVB7t1d/Vzuo1jD5EMEc15s1Gzqs3sQMdTTIOAHWgUqPqNXYT4AXPwKzWopz09Sdor4rKjsf64i5zA0c0KxLbiGyVd9LmmcxWq5xiOKP8MzAvTIPVnr3P914GHzy/onM4jMaHTGperhTgxlZBqtKhAlHMOtsxEIpmWkw0@hEeI2ErOl6F9f9tj/sjdDHVBfjg4@roJ/GK1JsvPbhzPrGvSTyfIUKJJPt9sdKGza6zXbbTj@mZASN75WQx@DfymXLNmIwfNx548HP5ibTfStCqPJzqegkQz1UQGBOpv5zNn1zrzxbOE7Xk8XQeR8Bq6OjgNUml6hKgaGRnB3xcoqwSjqZoHdfsgMVTCnw2U4bz0nRMpIyjQL4N/wavvDkYHyA0ZmPuxwHN7GEhv@bp6rhSigkAv2TEQn8HlWZDTzvl34qZ1aHe/5sfzTqpmxblaG8U9gH9lP2d4pfeP1Y8Uy8PCFLamcZPz9Q@25awmj9sySZkP2SnVDLUvivPaUfW2HDMR/w1JSqosNqeWiZes7F0SIpLWRoC3SvoE7GNd9@5VP9GHdzucLLYuz7e/2dZQvtBTFILUx4p1TunH7en3MGEDCKxQEk8WWEDMcxyih7E535FjJeYia6YIDm6kuP5nUgCSxkr92BWSfOxhN/ZmIP4/C7RmV/@2h3F4ZOxPblxtqr9aKlw259SvPvCdZDUV4p6tgY5nFYp1GSISVVWPiQpBixtkP2JwZ2HMyI0dVVp9FHjPOg7Tailkw4kGFzA7ypZYgmegkP6ZAQFIDjqaX4daFkSgZIRZpqY2uu3Bkt8V1YKxEPSGOWwZx6bYb/ELYWfyXiukGSgSSLUWxd4FzYXdC4l9hVpqK0uaHAPZglm1B8zGHcNA3oqIvsZ9G7lt4kbxu9GLApI8ordTuVBCSexrEQyq5iyJL9geKMyANgih4GXz5JfoPHExngjsLducG0Mm0CGXd1STynDg@jZaNPJeTzcgm66PlzXdOWwFN@WyJFsiePk3VgEEMaCJVzNCosiRjgoo4jEq@SLGDfLtviC3MqBu9AOEXJsfIdOHdRcySUooofIt9VVArBsHSQE6bara7DUllOdBwLRc4ImX6IHgT/D6TJAvhbsOME6CG1jCCAj6IkQWVawfaViOLfKkWDod0IqWl@OgnB3Jkdc6kbJrU3M/avARLI3pmrDycU9rCXWkAAZHI82DDlV5ukXbqwdXqbsGVx1JMMO1fjlJBzhZoq7sHNrJ@nadmVVroVfLGFzWdNRoV7UFS85Y3bBUk9bJliW3nxLEgwOFvF/3BW6ABECzxx6SVbrcY5KyelTI0DMtSSMeF0dcQkWJbePai1WxFGiMzI2C81X4pQALqM@NxvJ137MRJsnhuNuEgzsWhRFDwMB47bZJx8ZMi6CzLEHHgI51mXDkPwZpDpLU4QA4ZOofpCaCL1jAxFsJLQ6jCMM4jDrZ0F0tK0equxp5NJ5FCN/dGQA9V7fKqlcmQ5wIfE0HSXz4p9dw4oDx7XbGYxZ6U5SqPtIlbGxxKyPN6C0hmNJrB0dLHdgGPan9tZcSwPHbxhcD2R8QthPvMn8kRCLfqhGlw28e6dphmO306oBf4UvRW6WeIPatKVhxaiHJ5kllkXKWBexaNldejoz1bzIrUVpmwBTSgsKRFxS6yLr185FxNUhgz1iIJ@oDcXZLNJ9aDeQYvf7WjyC879uAQadr2ujkxqgKSzQO6k@pBiPHam3PTxKKATDegKPAHRlMjzQZo2VIU5@pVkJ2nXlAijY2LsUmrJ769HM6myloKKQsaVtQPzrWegM5FKBRkaVAcLzRfWCJVFG667BzdjFC00qrYWibOhHlI2eRFReqaWjvjE46Z@OsEnechfehag9MAX1HHLJSgijGtW1KveH@cIP7QpOPa9Sdc8E4WVTNcd4/EbbX1GQ@JFdXQow/513GngzWEH0HH8mUMw2qmfRpfDdnU0cPv@yHdhn4bx22c84uHjnB6xw/qT0W1AF/xQQtfI1J2HzxxfhsOw4bvWSxaN0FzB1BunTDOF6WReueQwEXRyjkaA4QWJxN/jeIw0XeblWljIivqfkj1e3i4@WPZFflFh1ugjADnAlWMWFOxDOiXHJMP5tHgvw8W3Mhg4XoiMcO0HLPYiGL8GEpEaJoKxQuaeWYLZCNyZPYjxaXeW7lIMwgkGWvJ2PLySJkjR57SLt@HCKPIGLQU2RX4jZxRlLcoM4xDiw/xhchde/cHYAwI/gH7@xSJuWcQINMT1VLSlgPcrMsoo4ELmgT6N0TQSwyjm92EWGkSAtmdxqNHk@UPUIMsfWBTJMHv3uBIlMgUbH7wzLtWGIac9t3FSWRbLNsXtwCVIZZrKPcyw3vfsZ0n4UYnLJ2c4MFUl5JSB9EOk6gCV8BrPmHmtiTLHVP6@xBQKj@21GAFLi0zOjKtlUwm1ciEPFJ/nV1RrjSYwGCdi1JOmHsvBdDRefiT1Hhw7FkZmW0Trjm1/1xCYma0Ek@VKl0hbmuPjvGjF8YkxTZRiZGkGPITbV3rWbB4n4qzURnkrteffocNDNAvtpvSkovu7y7KPk@INWvSqiUaLFOGOQUqL@vtpGxrefngEkTB5e9WmEaONQ0Z7zo8GqBiZNJUeTyHiPol7jB5doBzW2wXamf3zIFHjRnIq5KlKigS5RHpi4HZ02oRxadxD4wsME8crXD1I6QXnLD0nVV4@c4FBhjGBAeKq2MuE51B8ght2VoyP6HaAXqqN1kJ5HIngqWxaOOig/5pgFJVfHu5Ii4f2PJM/LzKkmYYEuwrK9S1Iyt8cXk/bM4JyjxQg4gtIoVt0b2y6fHyrfrQtkA8gcGlKlpa@uTQ2xhargA38M5PaM1wDh1XJkhGJigpCm4YGkAXYpfQHHm9XcfXnT5jj0bpBihFsIPhzCn9WZQkM572e09TGIrPuHLPYktwsbbbIlLlIyFD8juSXoshLXdq4AgCPMYbypTxAwLCmhD0qBSj0jsl5EURlH0HBUh7FEj5SVNTQznNBOhJVZni5ZuTILcrx2oSRWQgEFhaL84SIwJplcZYQCkx0C3Excrxa3J4wByyIFe8zxaErZK9Eaah7jgkIj4StHlFO8yKdkxxMiS/X7Eii5m9KfZ0zUnPxVKCPxvA0k4@nbuQiqZFqC4Vo0UhJoIdt1hpJBFLYJsJ6VPixP3JNMUOea5tQY5MRWWVI@@whbqVucd@W/c9AbJFTtlpjKHimZ7jafrX5ipVIUPZvB2AXMu5/8ccbqwxTFSLyqgAKS6d8XVK8H6QFawJnemwVbnRVoD0dn0BtaUc98bG1uxuJ@noxV3ZGV95kLZfLIQ9fmLHvlWk1niT5Iyea2@ldDwbO@PanyccLh4Z@vM1@EIw21Qbagx4BmQiyo0mfL4ZAHCAr5s5IP1bc6l/3euYNDKigxL6DXuOcMhiCoPnH1zYvH1t0/kMg5fz6MzYQ2/ez0MJ36/I6U0JRWigojRbBNwmlPAPy4IcemmdrRRUBw3FZGTPBtGWXyl9wAsGLTaizKHqx/SW0Tk689waDUVoc4w3BGCjgyV28wO6uWSDHWVDBSM691wGFo00L78YfGG7FmMVkdQSn5iV1zYQKC4@h8RtevzYbpxKnnxMwq0CTV7GZqxieOi0S/YQtY8U/AizzIaD9qNxX7jjVITrFM8NMLwU4fAKMXuTTC7c@kSw2HYlJmn0/NxJ1MbpZitUATbdpKaBC2VP3UkseyK6Jmzib5XtIwxzDkDhhyJXHlUBPsz9uVLyZ9nqPGxTpFgDu2H/7gEgqAJJAKX5ATwyi/R8ZEOvdWDwRXt/gXR33xx0s0MYClvWsU/r1NlWpVMTSeHVVVCrb8JDJiMp2Rezgh@1tsQPv2/j@vFRYWyvymLtjf4GP2@rjndgGGHTAudq5nOzAK6SV0G0MjbWxi5ec0lK6uNQubZWLgXNa2Uavfnj653//7z//5y9ORb78DV@26eX0s86UzWadpc6Xped3RXw/3TlfXro4XRqfL/eLyGX/oqDho/o044bWo9nJhZXkWcD4SmakaptNwWdkUaGu87tyJ7/A6LIpkp3AScqvAV8cRWNssuMZ3z10o7yAHby6cyC@kwckkgB0jqfx0DsdD@3vYL4BSgIuaAbK5Vm1os7tMRqMzqCVKkkZiIeWrDceurSEgRTQFRdmrIw/DLwhHoDf0JKXm2dZLvz607bkX@fzftDfHs3EyllKrOTESlqsJBL0k19/DV/tJcdH51zOBruBRCINKaFmAa0MReDTOo@2D3TVTozclrVEN/YgJBWlgjKzE1xab/7IV4bvWwv61hO8MFPwCQnpmLBI8svS8A665QvkuEtEPG1oodCWmxiqzFCo6P7FFZAbsB1AWPMVE2RzBFWioo8ckvHJUV9kX1t0mRABRrI23u2S3OMHmIuWhtLkObKVwluOyHqev@LcWGRfaEIbU7j@EAHSp/BuMkeOhMvJZYuNvI1WUjPZCdtsn2Q@NnWYe1Nlms6F/ksYTMDG3CbhlobSrUXacbN2RSR8rV0xqkrETb@FZRS5uh5M/bH0VqDaUaC@6NruWJKwRwkQw@GQ/Zv3JYzOCVSgqFi38F1Zc9EdYdNZEobSMx062M6y4sgggvM5BbL9NSbbtkNOIoodmAcIKW3J13P9QSCDrkyI2H13coGXA7o9uk9tymozOs7DK1JjGI96GuksQSaL81CeoSnJ8cTtX7lpkTwYtSbuvA7TFqx8pp2sDS3ECEyIBAqfrHpR8xTC3CLZJUQR3RQyHMK7CwZzeTsa921Cu5xglypRkFFXUAgi7ESU9L5G@ipGx5Crf0cnmCjfG7y1MlIOsTTyoqGRhJQwvWZIzO6JjqVqMGVHC07CYlS1ZCpekIWucaK9Ir0vjOQDDBEg605IJ0DpibD@GuvH2anvDd3I5DQeWMrP3ykKnhdRnukmSjZGstSVp/nwwjvECtaRn6NBIHhuUtGMrCep1JOzQN7mljTnEYrxrU3xHVf4@v45ur@MHEPE0dDnwTI2Q4VXYGRFnQz/AUJv4PYBv/mtO0dWPEum3jx17NPPZ8PzldTZ8OvZbzZhIodkNctmRFLqstWIJWUFZkYnHXlVRmmBijR4NoxmOBsKdmExSACIOKnTz875VwcQOkvilfNnSSZIpMsQE@fb9TkI3rmHZjKKhZO0ntgrtur81Ju8LWBupV/sQ/5g8y9goTaVdEoP@5xJD0CRm@6v1@xxEjgbhdzLQv4l7IT63iwz8a5xvs0E1xfeDJYSAW5nYeo5@y3CDRFC3M0CtwgfZ9BOvtWEXU8C6aMkh1Ap5lSPpdkKymSZJyA/UJmipaKHi63zuKh7RBPBtACWU3kpFBRbDhrcl8L5MxhdYT1ugONa3DmEORKNDNhEhE5QMwhZ3b3yEIfaSlyWyc0pK6oYupWAQPc6SWO2GI6GGblYs7PLRVxEo9PMYCO3kYvL6D0RjUjoklxMLT8V@fKbV//46@GvyWmyXHCOJ/A7Tf6aXN9I8iM8wNsL9XaTLCe3MNv6XXLuwB4YHl/94@9QvvwTwMGU@Rb8K68pWOvzZDlToiJfk@V1eMgXClDv//35z9CGJd6x4VWsS@20IMSKiiJVd0i8C@mijq3kbelyOKyQXxbCYAND2JvDC9pFzQobOTqlS0qjihtPBr5S5ihyiie7rClZCvFJhjKngJURFyhhBRkGqSwoesIw3VBWG8i8IZri52fZ9QB2AD9Law5dpbbceBagxdASb4ugA1NcI@zn@aGce5PQ1h2bCWVSUlRLSNzaybF240Xx/wE)

Elixir has the same string interpolation syntax `#{}` as Ruby/GolfScript/CoffeeScript, but there is a difference: it interpolates single-quoted strings.
I use this to separate Elixir from other languages. Elixir code is at the end of `''` string on the longest line:

```
#{IO.puts 295#
```

Elixir has `"""`/`'''` delimited strings, but the syntax is stricter than Python's: opening quotes must be followed by a newline, closing quotes must be preceded by a newline
(not considering whitespace).
So I moved 4th `"` on line 27 to the next line. In Elixir most of the polyglot is hidden inside `"""` string inside `#{}` inside `''` string.

At the end of `"""` string we need `}'` for Elixir, but it must be hidden from Python. I use string interpolation again to achieve that: `'#{'#'}'`. In Elixir it is a string
equal to `'#'`, in Python it is `'#{'` followed by a comment. Code in polyglot:

```
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
```

4th `"` is to balance double quotes for Pyth. Note that `" """` is an error in Elixir. CoffeeScript also uses the `"""` string and it has the same interpolation syntax as
Elixir, but it doesn't interpolate `''` strings, so we are good. `;` is for CoffeeScript. Reminder: we don't use CoffeeScript block comment `###` for the entire file because
it cannot contain `*/`.

I moved zkl to the middle of the polyglot to simplify the end of `"""` string.

It was supposed to be just

```
endif#\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
```

but `endif` is on the odd line, and Retina and Make clash here – Retina doesn't like `\`, Make doesn't like `\\`. So there are 4 lines there instead of 2 to fix that.
`{` on `# {\` line is for Red/REBOL.

Answer (score 5):

## 298. [Joy](http://joy-lang.org), 13850 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::   _@_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 1xxxxxxxxxx      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      # ????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa













































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:peseps>Ex Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:F 4, ._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8ogr ca34 16  prstd    
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4@cLzI1KgbpEUCZAAH@JDZJVKJd2rvlWlakl163ZTLBZIgiSuSIAFkBJZkiq6e3Z73WPvrLenx9F@jG@7ZzxrrydivBM76/aOPRNhf51wzCf/gPJjY8Ox4f4HveecTIAgRVJVbTtiPyxIAIl8nDx58uTJk@@m4fV@9rMIXuyZ0592@86IjUxvxNqudWG6Kns4ZQ8My8vpGUlCX7tudzww7ZFXkiJMY8wbGe6I9Q27Oza6JouArc5m3x2rPzLdJPNMkzXNvnMJ7hnGbPOSHdotqw2Q2Mg5N23rjemCW5axR2b/enA9Yi1nMDDstseGrmWPyDXH2DMDPjrj1jkzmt7INVojy7HBKc/Yc7tvDJptg5H3oWvyQNsMQLXOKcy8S4GxJ47rmRCD0zI9z0HLIlgaruU83n36yYJ/Lc0@MQCpYd@cLESvaeyFZbrtxRA6@/z04GDRNsM@UxybHdxGScuy3fHIORwtws@x3a5pG0xXi6q@6JgHYo7MfiFdSM85gduB5UJuGiLXSrOcsceDpukC8UUWXlqjngoBTh1OcObY/SkzJwAMcOyAN3PELMwtlkun0Sf8T8yWY7dn4MHKBDgA1xwMR1OmMNsRPABOjsu8odEylbbZtwbWyGyzvgXYOR2Bjccgw9m5Ob10XMh4hbMiIeINzZbVsTCISIEnIbM9MpvjLnPGo@EY0PNY2/KMZh@8NaesbXaMcX@UZE1wA@KR/WXPtAVKlt3FdLyY2SAEG4oAx35TA9pY/T4DdM4RHYzaYzvocIn26LVpEpZmG0Htz8gFkIy@56d@PuK5aDDcM9fpusYAGLVtEg0@P3zGvJbjwhfc6JeXgnVgWsaI7eyw6P7TR1FWDciouk0pIGmFXTHGIr4juzD6Y9NjA2MKcdsjKFzMofzzQ0jgnUU3oiUWzWSYnmbZLMtCYSswPZdmUCSKYIBSq2c0uPNML7CsBnyfiyYxno5rdK2@yaF0nX4HAW0jx@o5psMznY0muWuL4thmmQLLb7PtHNuGZ5EVdYgEIWaZVszBnYcbIBQBAw3uTJbHFLAFshMkge2xjjGw@lMOfThE8C2W09g2QAQ0NYCsFwBCUUcI81cY3qgHhO0ZFwBS6VvnKC7MQGJgbqXgldraSpHIQtnIo/R6Zr@PsQKhgES5AtuGWPOQ6CzEDHTUC7qf@G6Pkk94bafhBhy3IcUFIG8aKJVGUm3DDd8ghnSQNzoIFx3kha6BvQ7mDEIFf3lwy0Ne5QPS6m2iLUhXCKshMVGgaEgDCMYg6zJZBpmXhezNYPbmMgzwBAS28wxkSkFjhSwrbDMgVzHNgPQaIIN5r4Es0wAJDYFBlmqQpxogogGzaABUy@SYFKKrlkF3CJuBsEACLQthsmCGfNHyeEM4yHgNotQgTl0vzlgLcNNzkMhchnhOz0PmbYMbEEsHXHXgFh2w1QvgjmELQLgCsuS2TwijP@wZSAvIAWRkYDUgSA5wItjgH8z6doazFPlumiOrJd1IUKp4DRiWOL70QAkA0oQZDCtQYMAZ98QCCRgHgTQvrMae2QcuAhnSMsCMbAulHSWHD8caqShnoZoynQusSKn4z0XjkYhouliLgrxqm67L0C9Utl6ShIk3bnrm6zHWtTO8OiCdTBCsHcPqBwhQ0TFGVA/AO@pBfNN5tDuuM6DyNUBh0Xec4QqxC6LpEgF96lyaM9RnkssYDvsgz8HeBEKMjT4gc2mQPkDqQjhWjhAEwnCtngUAKSqQq5Zrtoj2IukQOgMSeB7FEtOr9zII5WGoWsiwoQNC1cMw9rjfL0F1Z7ZYpppqmxcptOFVx3yVgTj4lQnUhwJE04C6nCpTxCKAdE9XqZo69XPWcwbzSePi5TBIes/CKqB/aUwh9zogWcyJMQCNg2G1bkPFPQCO4TmIOeHxiueQtR07OgqgXLpQvUKig5QAyD7RZGQNTNDHHAiCOZ4lpFG4EWbNKbAyUSurkjrGMVkglCotEopbZEMWvLBAxdYet5BqGLdlEwdBheBRbVUFuFzpVNEARc41jTb3htoFYhTSj6C2M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbA23HU5mFaiEwfNfpAI9RFQ2qBgSdxdOitGPKA6uJ2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4Z2IN@AmgdpAtQxzpfWuwNOPZ7Huu3xq47ZZMhZIA1AF@jltPpANO@MYc9AMEGbdaatqBUQiqRaaS2QxKoNVxIcvC1aYIf24Rk7z37BuuaQG2okTuAKXH6LAHDISWBSGHYvLa2DaAUJqE1nBJZAEwQouM4Ktq3HdMjHgFtJijxGJlndqlEQPHqzGTQALUPYE7QCGxgWRA4olQhfIxQWpoYjEpk/iemDSWmBcwIZR2yD/XRXdYB3T9UWaNyZ7Ra5nAk2MMhKWbZIYXm6AAVGrJVBDDV60mbD0AXm8NAAq@SzzmhGtw4J@GKij7pWQaKWNHAgDrdNgMVlnGB0p/eih58XCzELr9CP3MYvJJX4DCkkoDaHcmG8QglCApFq9VDEThCIUNaBhQyd3w7@WAXjt4dMKUTxI3YaCBtJDUVWCEeq2EocPdvA1KHfYRVnbNAr3MWd4A2vMESyE6AZL8dtlVThgqy8C6gA8d2lkAFYgZw0cu8C@UFMeMJSg2jHzAjFRdvLo9QTs/avlh/QdU5HDoulAwudKYoyXiWhbjL4e2UWFBFxKHdPF@jQk0RxXp@NOJtrmEf2kFUxLCkgj5pgKQAIcZbACDzHB5jCGEq9QRL4HdJEp8zE1Shtm2iSmq4Uw4Ekge1MkQ0ZZbrghi8wLqBVz1@HaISn0JVYLTbKFmRHFTuFyNXkaP3xk1rstjMaKGl@qUnXRgu62ALwwVdAwpRLNrxovEy2VPIkJOccoajFAXlTxk8kicVsjzWgUYLVAQHIGhOpnYrJs8VMTnJ5PGoU5DjYMCAXDVjXzOGo0XsvgQ7ZJrBOZRr@iqzLtTaigJPBe0IE3RIqehguKBeQCEELbtYbDcNdg3Sw2XKZI9Co1pIb03NBnGZdjuISxACcQmnV@VReG6LDEqoVsMUoHdKOVUScwR8T0pQQBksUilRf6IFKXncjdQZbjm2qXuAxbgGEmdXgYoOFUCMkLFA57Ba1qghtJR793x9ZaNSAWYDJQrEZjseVu79fhQVJDV4VkkJEZGoI@dkhGUjFof0oucbjg1oS8CplSq7GvVcKHH0fSOBJyCrZCMn@4QV@fzUOh@3FzPaRkv0JGOpA13Jao3ksgSVPy8NlXVUjc5RFZT/KFIVmRfDE@hbzEu2mKGy8OaaHmq9FYFKKIdjiIHg1aUk4kGF3Yyh96atvlAJuAkKO5dGTUD/XLTUA0GUFDqBX2hvlVQOBIsDh8Oe7Z5@WhFlkTummpZdmrPoOy2jT9ab6F32wz4@fHi8e/yNxhIYfatZWrRIWdlCHqva8UTp2uNUVtVLm2EYM8CPGuthY8B5P7IknJniTEKq0rQFlcvEJ@fR8WeLJAFNCMlBMYAZ7wWVhvsBpUtqGl5voRJm3UQCogyC@H6Zcsh8mIEBUUd3w8fn2fjNG8y8RaSGwh4x648NDsC3TB3afjgVHRcUMN@p2eE1IoUFLdSysf9zZgr79PH5BLXmRWRIlQ6xzCdHB/vHFQLbM7xzs99XyEvKG4EuZbhtFXi@P26b0jI/IP7A1GIJdYY46tOE61ICt1pzBJ7lLVsBHwBgE0d1mNIf@EnzeoD73mLayFZpBRxA3wRhUa8M60OtD0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhVlkFVktrrMB1vtpq5XLmdrYYrrZaszjbYaADUootx9cbXXA69xS0UWdapFCrBfonj28h7pESCU0BxcfM6zOV4vL6ErZeFItFvdQetNCcvqm@IIknMzmeSkX9jk@15VGbM@R/f2KNYuk4f2tx8Aux7@4e6o98z6KjjjowqNGATXCsmdwODjS0POAR2@k7XYdtQRiuHfoRgtq0Mpm7Xce@lUMGWmJSIzhyAfIX@2uMIdQ11htqOFKocHOVj3oYtncJUlrLZ5BIRCEClSL/6pfGhQHkmqX75PCb@1CJaLl0OjCn6QIShMIQudDUCtmSBVMgIlXgszSBwSjGrdLuOyihYQRMtBB0QcDdmfNSS5KYamqp/6Uofc25RfEvnekCa4ENZy0whEh2@PTZ48On@092vzgb6bnc3Hc2XcwD4SC@JuhCao/TDUvrFi@amCwEF4Gy4WLxAikwhgaK3x0@9lwQ3Cp6UTkCS7mGD46FUolNAmxQWE7Uo55ElLrYheMNQe2gHrAW8pCHvRcjKLu8r4l3k4ygRYAsBA3DKHbuGR7vQoFAYkjEDw@aZACBugqDbjI7GAoCQlEoajxAuqDxgH05vVkfCDZJoMxAhIQTNo1AvtnUpdkFKkBgnpBdnhAeE9nMJ@kcGk02QmuarKA0rRHvgXTGLg41WO1w2sB7Rud@ABolLsR1NCbRNFu8D4gHplSAimpAAwaaKdDQAdlPvWomJcHg4xmoqXrYjQaNr7SC3boAX2EP9nqG3TJ5a1YZoIrHlOE@i47c1K7yzZShvAFOWSP5MfG74eE1yvRTnwDUTxKMr1EbTvTPkOx0BuTpBbUG0fGhXxlLw@moBylWWkw2Ks7QtBc1Uq6vxuJlGgWKRoEdLTt2Fd3Y2IiWotVoEkz3wbSDpvtoSoDpPpkUMqE/FU0UIkkmdK1RCLSrR29qPuRJvI48MEG59sYaxoxaqZSpJ42aJt46vuOQFUB58K3gC@BE45UKGuNxuXqJHcmgXYTSvoe8c9JyraEgwddAXPFvQYMMEQEaH6hruGYZNef1FBlUXFBpTawAY270rJY@q59dnbUTZzfRJIaOl40KaK8xiC82ULuuMx5CtVLLlhStHo/XMqV6uVmJpqNbsVhB6UNERjz@cSGeMDitY1FoN/djZ2dRIKmgTq3VcwneJKnH4wGhAA9oE7Whdo1F1asCxN@M1@OJKISNR5PQmqlEo0CXFhLBo0Rje4Uz0QE0jz3sJoc2d7jHk6oj6jHH4vpNc9ibumEPQZ8A6ADYvzcbKoTCQIOtYfn5hocPVzdz7RC/Vub@oOrFrgWU5sMpl5sSx/QsNTds7ddrF0pn4IyM1OcqqHRBJLKXim5EU4qSkhm5cEiU7CeWh0XYsE1n7IX7QZZ2z2DsYHvaG4Ow9Mf0k8BV1lAyWz2HRTcfAHQWdEJjLYL96QrvlfcBtFsq3ChETw@PUOy7pj2iwW4L5CIOhPM2o0ZIcNHj9xzm8sPXahBbmcKwNEZkdW3HNRUgCYSQaGiaJjJIVSbGuw@pXX6r11S47kGU1CywTJCIB33HINpycR3qrR4OQuGh9QBBjs221Af50QHxqPK8cM12akuioSPH7UENAalBSawHuTUQDinHG7bV0QSCSjGoW@ccue4JVeIla@u6nm/lOiXfDbkCiN2DTEKd2QYF3HdSNHCMi0ze541WvwXx9OjRPm/ZpaBupbYhtvIbA6c97gMHc63u2LS7SbYP/GTZzsACMvjh35z3jx1nxNsg8LGq3chVemsw7hvUIl1sNK4N13KaTp8aquuCzvyPXc/oG7yJ7Lvufv4ENJHnpycVtRTylDIuBmvjxl6S5dFyeh6GR0RoEMjvvPY4Y8qbORnrLX@qDIoZ4ZBHh7GYKAN55Ntvo71fpLCHV9gX0H6Ak2Sg3SPaOPQZWAqPRfKIE2dwvoGwvNLSN2i/UkMM/Gnk7xKn0ISwvdJ0sr8YdTpz1hmyPldQNPVn1lmy5hNo5jTYMEo57gln08z5CQPKk59gUs2iPyG8ggHQntn3xzeOQTHBPnyo2/uoPtnmJY4v8JktptfCFsPYJgmNAwCs1TNc71ajCsrUUOG@pcgGlROow1KouUibKSY64MpUUqBRwwdOPC49HWh4UNtup8qH04AxLJcP26R41@BmA0DsVMv@XIdV3jCmaDTwRlAJNwhByaRBxVtJDYaIPerxkyhIWfJStZdnEz2tnE229@spj4jQYfLZ2eTjtP6FnGQ4I2XzXqprljG6ldSib95L1uqB2GCJyTzJIB/GdsfptxXeJQ/5DxhTn7sXDIQGc2JI4ION5frTYSwcYhfTlkBchmbS3IK7kHXV2x5Cc28CQFAartj1efLimtWgBrtQvWHfGtXZjTpyGj1M/Gjs2ouzdLhK6brG1JPEOHqF7R5/8nktXecQpIGB3ewFnlsTf5IX6MGg9@BcOjDhbICRNaKKnYY9LUyvpgJSE@qRBfQBBo@gzIKIRIoQ9WvzepaWjjkC1ctEzL3pIMnM@I3a6RujkWlz3uJjHavJzTulRTQViv6@6OEssTR1A4OiaaEboFhmJ6eP9o@PVeBQLxbdx@7iEhQ7o9UDfWNVon1KhhNfYh@3o@xjDBNnGAsUKWhMNER4YN4yMDc0JyB2FAVd042BZRx7eltgTZ3rFJArXIJAOKejNSIaBcBiZhzSRMBKS/F/bvOWk8CzxKIsQZQEcsfulYC2Vlwd29Zr1YN6g9RQ8BLlbU@awFfZjJH42tTixD@uNcCRKmgykRYIaajV2AZIN/Its8pb9rKWVor1xCar18t8/BECok5PEwLF5DJD0JN31pOAFDgfilZZZ2GKoR8D9SthKI6fBjwrCb4FZN1xc3q7lMqbuhwPkFXegAV3lBeRXDIFjqPoT7wgEULzNObnW8zP5ggl6zk1shemrkJyfASC9OAgSYynkm1UmBaP@5hxQC8MF5vOJfbM8Tyr2ae5dZ2@xeepBJV1SRBGQPIpE46ujAWD6IblGcoZZsZsQiWfpigoQe5U0UBLClNGFrE4u0JiEil1pCK7vkYLmW3qjNhAxvmMnL43fpsW5ONjB5B9LOZnhnUOEhpi8BxFx5kk@423@dEpdOENg9TFgs6rXMjhcFzntOxzh/q4A1MjrWo51DOD0IPz/u2QHcvr0WPOa4AD96uvws4bNDv0WOKBunrFICJZUCei0LAhO43UMb2oP3FJzPMD53PRNs3O2O7SiAuamfL6Dp9KsUCeO82mtcorEAHnwvjvJd5AVmLJ09WsqvmlBzt4oFoE@cnbRLOkL865YHN0h0pqBKHE@79@qw30v507PaivsG82MDRAU8CcUjorM0sExQ96LM9Y3ik47lsGEYZMd4FsGS4kyegHhuWgaeBRUUDfGGA3qshx4E18gC66hs045nwUxH8vj2TZQIINcru1yu/CHBQeFXV5Q3OxTUTgOpdlUiASsjwTzAnvdg413FHg3o2UP1GEETPzfO@NR2P@BHX4zky0hnivK5vCZzpnNDUTGqRG0zLXZLlrnI/bjjI87wZqcX6J31nqadxLAa1EDIE10Lg8@TyBrtWF6t5/r/I2q19Tl/S6iys8e@wNlSa17dv8iwrCYE0Mbp8/V3mxxDqKwLCaalafHu/JiQI6MIoYAU7h/DolRDRrgcx9ozlFVaj34VwWjKaCxKm0Eol0ZsVw2nC4Ojy2Tyl8sbg89ERtcXos63lI8Tl8Cu@bowSLWX135CpUV9bA6Ct6O2RcKcyXDcbe8hqM41AY8wIyjR7rmBwrpNa4b7gz0xoWn@HhD06s6ucW1YYoyy2nb3lYoPurpKY/I2gWF86ipEdo1NdaRsk2NESxHlcC03Ip4LRGOFNuBVu9h0zjM9RwHmCIT1RnFbFaziXeKzWIHjSG@XN5pfZmKVbvIZ@UfqtvQFW@skaY63XEXs07ePXS8kx6LCfs@VJER63@Uvv5UuD3J4b7B@/ibM/qOx47oec6AnVdoAJ/LufpMC0tw1aolz1sXiOG/KHdWYYa/a7Tzxe6KQMeK3N97HZQ9Iv3@wq5QEhp2h1CyteAHFsT75Wi/Tzlnt@VQbQ6xcVpfSHjmlp2maQSgzqrUwdtAxwRXJ6yg3SBQqop3oe4ImIcy7k0pv7756g9VpHWrz2GU9KoQcHDAMUCGEYu17J/ntiy62Nrv59QugV2@65EhDL3vG9CfUXPW1nK9LT2gSG0dPr9RVSnPzbH5tK2xlHzSxMXOa5pZ7w/UmmRjE0xBICjDjgjP/D1RjQO3wtrrKrxa60wMaDVbt6tzcwLtSEo4ENsPT8DwzM03A7RtcfDuVyda6DZx@tJ1hv6Rdppz2GHLh8qhwp3KEtzKrpn0r220cQbeTgvppJNp9NChwkN5cx9rGtMZYKwX1r8ORcx2cxinvnF4Ts3ZFweB5ElPPNqpQjSV7XtyXOxmLIt2xxN8fme0rTpOP0PySkQqm0LtTFQLmmG4bocu6XuiLnzbNZ74WGfR7Ozqt@C1zaieQn0wXbzukwPjzW9V24qOJo6wJGu@c/1PTihkau7YsHFptgtxOcc9lfrkqJDRFML6vbaUsc1VKdp9g3@muSz6@AV1cxaePNCQ4wC46gxHyuejfFHFoTScArEstrQUOmZA5M@1yj6RvvLsee/VnqaOHivcp6YZis12TdbqzwMLZALNj7nBqdDytLIsaGJNTLcrolNlT5OoBO2qySwP5y4lMiHA6Nr8hX06yTlrM8Cp@nwlt3MuLz3osSn5rQg2KyHeTVLQKE6N6ee/14K8Mm0Bfk6Htzd47ZQ@FvYDfoepX3VzL3bVazdc3p2z@zx6bLB16rCAfw44jserEMdsO72WoxEU3hmb5iefafffx96omjkgtJxOktx2sc1f7hg5YPgTo0mOIjXnf13xojLDjSsLDU9cwz1kueMnKGp0Ncqr33s6@HPVTLUH/3@eTuR1jb1gSL@@@eFf2fbsms4o@GQXo1hf@zRg4IqtFTzLr2pw@e8INmZ43bVN86gqQpLVUyIoUH35SKmaY1aPVwiyznb7DrNVs@6C@mmaYxs6zzl9/rwz/dquyJlLKY8Qmu1bwF53amK/FIJu5/g63BVposOJF6tBYY1@sqyTjpajaoMjfOWxztE0cRK2CccKo18zWqJFvuWXo@t0QxoaJJU0MPLRybQsAp3MS1jpWZFU8NnYlhM11jJpaSko0KumGlQeLSV/UtzE@hCRSyT4Y9VCIVTSRiFJrx8CLnFpCLqILRCXbdgP8dfc7OhllZydm/c9W4LTN5j3wYVDR9LReBuFze6wcWHDvP6ziVNVaP13bMVjKH@bKjNDFu8VmWA3k/hqi94N0AbG5trB1xya0dcyJ/WVwzHglcDXpCp45W9a31r6PEnUzorx@nE9ClopS8OJnKqTZc3s0WWtc0OHx9B013K48ChEVzQTpQWjvZj9zqKea6ScZFmO10Q90qfzTz7flcpNEtnJi1njKA2Vb54anYNnN792Brh/NAl/ELMvGxG052wvz42POvrY0jZKjbEJex8jNINr3XGryXwnhhdq/XpXEYESAoCi8ml/DVXMNDqdl5c9iwPZ1cFhjVdVshynImR6xrQoljic7FTP1i9Pyv1fF3YUt/LOt6d4RSXz0zJtK7P3RpR/6t4r2pUrpp3thaJy/FgOPbEazkONH8r3D89OCd779IC4MprELqsZ/RHy/uwQ52xoJ@J6nJmXKWnf9PqO132zUKagToH6hmq7UsY5yFU3M9w0pBrL@FEivs9x0SxC0Thss97DXlrZphi2dZofT/PaIQTiPw3JobXKbgoIvUYn@qDD4WgnC6nyOO7WwGztZp31PzAeSfO2G2ZaAw2YAg3GESs5p4/4VnUGrZ5GW6/rR3XgYrSsccjxR3ba2uF/NpaocQmhXyIDVjs6/tPnsfD3EATxO/ST01oFo69/nRmWjmbYIHJLBtUtNVydN6338p4xPeLOabZyXeE2cVNbVokrh85y1pCz6auOXrvphQI//HgkdnCMcU7437qPHFsB2qjIQjKwbHJF0HPzQJZHhCDPcZlvkCf9p3RnBDYFZUQ1zaModmE/O3PTO9TF3HAj4yRsaIqol5DahkGpjt5xeo3TfdL6g4MmVc1ducR@tScUKtjNcPwMqiMWi2uLGNP3VwZmRvL8YaOY/MnSds0vLQn66UKVAX0eP9RdBXn/s/1GCxtuc0n9eiCTyEx23yV/qq0umbT6fPnmglLtsUnDBiuZXqpx7jom@zyWaaA9uWtlSHba2XIrNEEmuyF4dEI/vJGyAykNvmA@UE9w205OEYmDGum7oRWat8hpoPlBHxWQRMIPwGJZbTGYs@4u9DqD5oDeqxsSoRy89hs4kKkJm1vMDImtzOT9xmJtd2h6V7BimhfXGGhzrPYM2inxO@utuZaWPNUtYb0IEm9ciCdZvIotmW23hjYn@YQvWa91nPukObUUzKu6MUOFSPqX04ZtPR3aUman9cGCk3fVEY91wTld7Su49vfd2LJSMl4YOLw8/z4zErV1fF6lFhn@Uh7IFxdUxF7noEsCfY/4/qhsrtS80Tw8D96@LUUVMKNfNbfiwFE191j@4D82LXF63048JnjjTrW5AjwxhUJq8QJJisHQeDFSwaatlYlAnLPHvd5v0Q3NClr0KbmmEL7bipKn8T1yFRM@0KhnbEmt1Pk8HVmqV3cxHFkthWxMBzHIJTH/pKzwJt4LxlaDctGnAmqpThhJ/msmBu6jLiXvmQAfcsZKUOP3qmh9@zw8dGpOvS05a3@Hq7UuKXHza001wvpUGfVl4YbGgnlc9XaljdKPTzRlL3Hhyp6WEFvPtahwAvH7OZeK3tExZaJRspY2QpCV3O0XEH89PTJ48RsVSiL7fVcZ2DGw857JydJXPXytZOlzuHQB1A6Os5kZfDDfU2LL2Hf5zaNG66SnktiWgXp1ITWKDDjp3yjijuVq5YzNNun06H5OVSeKMG994w@vzKRT40Lq4ulkBVXEooKKiuq@Ww8NG0bGtumG7xX5ee5NURp2aJXir9WTlRBzSGTcjPLtYd1cwEWtRiWFnMUPiyQlr7NrSNLgZLR7aEpZXh/X8Q0TVtF5xOjA/nKcisza97DspHjvnPxHoPMpmi8KIGVMgKuUqw7J5lvKwMQ3Sl8YMe9sARjc@UEmXUAAuv80gJ/adpTw1ZolGudelGC0Djdba2Xb5rvMVQVzP25wI1sl47@BfPtWaxFxvgdEZ@6oSB7ew8P7wpwLGi53tcnT5@zZ4bXMvp3eAxjbL4HxjPN6EsF@61wS7CVA61tF0Dpa@F1h8vLc4mdGG7bsaeTu4fnaNkrVu20yWoAC7/Ik9m3JtayuqrF@7WeLZ@AdFfcfIWH40//4Otfjsd2eL9ILynW1PNla3whkaf6m3rGYkYiEY/P7xsdXjbFFwwZuHM4rfUBv9fXbEMs6QGHYJWTWEiEm4@AFmHi8jvJB1Fjm1di2U2ppN3g0iO5JDOxLCrYiI1vJlbZjOE2SIAqU8413DmfbfprdhjthsuuGWkTIL60XBq@1FR4EWVZLGZiJYj22eGz/ZPT3dPnJ7V0/UaOiyV7HDXDgMj8xZwfZ9oypEgQAyp5vrMgLfrrQ3S0Uy9qIZ6fLAYJW0hZZS5lszTJ9zHM5pVhpFK0di2l3AB@isxjI1cQOWjFYfspJqqLpYclvuSrTxSVNzlomeKEnCix9LKIh4bnQbKE@@Je4eTKMhl05RGLzeCA8bqO0xYxeia7@/JjPNg9fPz8eJ/5CM5Y4dJqj3qVYo7vFYglWTEhnzoWDYNXWFQEiUJeVSrRgygQJqpGWYlWDNI@fcC94M2nDq41FKG3WGyT4AMFo0GmpP7rt1I3URVndMXBb9RHKsoE5dEDO8VVQH/2u22@j62/9t/fEN8dkAZNa6wlscJvxfo@pCgVt@HqbfFp31hayhdsWDs7akCibYyBKy9RsVrc0iVOuyzwMw7Ejjt@RMQg/t6X2AGAu@dA6@XCwnV8HIcObmYzz8o4mshw7bPKdnHPf@B5YH1EAlAf2yO@YYRYXh4BPlIDMZFkm4Qs33lZDnmM7mwAKzfNrmUzzwatyhyV2JfAZ9jILvHFpIpSjd4K4oPmhz0ovdGgH/J4a/cbL3U2Sr37le@lumUG5kn6IXz9kvjqgPmXufllCvP69g45s/jDSJhY6jjWPPKA5kjv0PEGNl@0OyMWbuTjyz9mDSBrLojS6J3HwJ@KzeQZnFjtc8goYDHIJbFYl8dnuvVYbzQallIpZCMcsFBpgqI54bMFVGDy1Osx7uDu2F4qn8tntRQgqVz4AGm3zi6uhOIA4/ESML50YQ0rr5rAXjs7TMZK2qzkyzw3U5vGy4z8KkB0E/xKlz1ErsYgDASZhQC3qggGlURCi2NQlEdRLYqiqO1A7UHuWMvgty0IIbMYEIvTyMTtHyd4zsXInfqbWDXx7IjQTs6bApCiQRVEprgsifWlT50RsMzcylq@vhRny/CaCseWPX6OC206jzyo3i5Ns2VR/pbRonypWO45qEx6sdIL5638AkGcIIiSvIxlay/Z2ejMrqc4bzJg0x8Jlg0zsw3mf5bqruBZnu7d23tzxRZ31kJisQcntoPayAEkhsX0lJ5Jafn4LEnZ7NIkiRSJaCA5uGPANUQHognERMu0vnSG3u7e/uHXjp6d3Np/inxGF72BJK/uJM4UNVmrB4ZoOFnzWfLwIHXy5OGBnxEzpPMhCQw6iUiJti4ls0YGgpxNZ11M2jIMF1O3GuMXfM3bIr4ZfR1qFOgWHlr6A@KlKWXKAU0MX4xcLyyjVi63DqUZvFQI9B5f1XML1Vj86qZW36me2ZHobU5YUhBeRtQtLARgOvO2NlPI7LcThwkLzls6xZMivHBZzCwvi/JmBrdBwXWFI@d8tgGMsAg5hNLrRwMiUlJTvteVpe@I69KzbYp0fh4U3zAlvE1ECOF8eh3FQ6BO/aOlUIrMNlkT@4v1QPXvW03J356D7zPmb4cUbDHGt9aIxSWxkTCPOCYOm5qUJiqNEsfiKO0IVpKt27LMhxeXoECjvvZsDE2QZ86QbyxJowGPTN907ID4fTTmw4om@9p4AP469Do2qWcGJLcCgYGS0QBVrj@BlBA7lk0SuCccxFfDfctEwtVBOxebxNWeOWlbXZDtsXgSJNrHmlZnwa5mmGjaxcyOypRns1xYWxQ/wbVaYbJ/0NZ2kxkCRs1QLbttTmLRy2i8VIf40T56@eIiGpeX8RJtsSf2nGsv7rUXoL@trZckxkiUTn8ju2XSoli8LSXAbhEw3yTG39W@WFR7nkSHk1RQFz8ZuY/BCGpErDMwhiw2tvlGOiqjz9hZzE7SziNKle/FZbNEgppI8CIHlVHIDpl4/R0z7CmLpSrABGjr2W18vbGGrKapah3MFEmcbeJpE3ugceGmFHEJ2qoQpERgK8hC0HAAjHghUTmDQxh0l3CvEJe2I1riTJvvU9@mgzShVLPqPRY6NGRec5SLxZLI0HmpWGTAfbfFoZoCsLfknK/LA3XFonegGTRoVSkyE@S3JV6E4o1wRD4Vq@UBnUho/zx/ET0DWLPd7Vo9F@/Yvg1lBff9KD0/PWgU4imZBavuu67Vxg4W2vsuEjTaxJbiUExTc16jZd5G@wSD4XZKDb6sH3f7OaACIy@I1EiYDItH6M14U9PWcr0IKHIBfGaxAhBLExo@ONw3zB/qWuK2XNj/7Gd4SJ8c27yfzzT6F4loLl2Gh1bOsRz7ePNMUTZrei5debBZN4zRmcyMVHbr0YXZ6zQPu6kzWWYZlk2ltvT86/Ohlt96WVNfT@pyrVBJntefnbNnz75423gblycXU/ksxrYjbO/oWtYgAZHSNisyvJdedHrW0mtNK12OAtyzMzx8T96WU6latA5/cnoFF/dUq6pV9X797dt4bRvSNJmeRfBMK3b0YB5YTNfjJ5ZlpdjZ0Gu34XZ6rM5PZYzwK5GIKUxYKDVuxwaTDtlNds1ud7xvTLm9FRnj62Akwj755osXL9Dwgi725liE59CZH0epYeQiTE/rf/aTjZvk1bPGzp99e5AyN/B1hK/v3TxB84mW@3hj4@OHD7PZJFCJm59989k3dnd3s4@SuWe13P2skt7Y@dM/2djQ9R09tVH3PK0erZ2ffyHr6ays/tmPo41nz77ueZgteGWYBkZ8FuDWUKc6Z2/gOu8w/JP5TTtkNtDc7LxheuRNBNg6MqVfI8J4KayQlhS@NphWvb/9335w9DoyilT11AsX3qPI60i@EOFGMMBXxv@6iFQjO@gtfxOZpiqVChi3/9u/h/DVrwEcdJnuwKOa82Hlp5GqUqEg15FqHgyarkO8//e3vnVXv8@DGlxydluX79fh2qJrR8K9jpR0KrXgWyvc0@4xZo96I9PBl8VfNryYUbah1X1cSyQSdVWBS21QoJSm6WfUYRNmLepviQTWZcZtWMhuxifCBtxeRIingKmIr7hZWBCrcYsXi/5eLLnKL/5xrmMpkt94YD6qVkEA6lV9q5qga@OsVIKUNB40Umy7IDvOA@zHip7JUfaKPRYkrsrpgi4nk8kHDTzolE2QksokMiMb45RhkTl6Rtjsi4WtIswPxmZ@PtTfPl5//r//@Q///Af0@yHd/wk3g7LbVie1VYttxesXjSq/WLUqV1356ow@HrB0qVAqpMgVxFP9mGnpT66juUz0hGmT4PL7NSPBVa3iw0cDv6oRblPlppmdcKkGH@RjFmS5PybkkU/UCFS8YmaMUruos6qfoGVX7QFkk6xvF@V6Vc/pR5B1mkwZV2S9TY85ET9F9@HagB/94bqPfcbCBp8bZMldyOuSayNA5u5rDk0pUqul6iZVE4GPBxuljUIpX9JTjbD1wlVeBTpyEZYh6rZaUHWQGm9rG@yYM3udJfzrLHHn9VxVG8JIBgdvRXEmESnyj3BVJRa5gqv@dqv2dqvhR10TBTWxo9SrCYERvNTGg3pCubmpqS8T5bL471QDY5muRJmhEVJSv1GUnZcArDYPNpp1onnnAULnwOmpNl7uAPjETm2n4uzRrVJRUeovq7WdeRACuQcPEihiHwCA6madxROJTUXZqK1MAwCsxxg0BiADb3Zuqje1nZubnR3479DzRrzB9mbn1p9es2uFn5l7HTnqrJaqnqXOBNvU4VtNVdFGTZ2BoQpv8Ae1jxRRkEm32FZkyLTtDJiYWdK29EwqN/k4vw8KUa2uYLulotS0fK6ucEn1SmUlhe8grRXycRVFUcPpNHDRl8peSZFX7776X/E@e/fV72NtD8WyKEVSW9goKPK2ATye2OzJkyd4P7Ft@MP9hF822qDFE7Sz@cPmPnw/gTW3oeJAUqGQlxsJbaqzyI6c30ax8Au3rmg0@k9e6cXtKG834@KoVx5Y/sKy65/8wqpLilwXkYItj/E0SREq9pAVUHyqaLzCR/M1/h6/wd/rEf5OW/g7fo0/dvoGf8cj/D1p4u@Zh7/T1/jbbeLvdIC/h6/x92SEv@dd/EmRCqjYm/fT/XQrrZ1r52CwWNpl6V66p7VR/0@bLD1NT1l64GhtMJnwS4PJSndYusvSdtrWNHAEw4ilR2jqwKsLvw5AceFnpdMIPN1iEEsfgPIjKuh9DXIsfibVoOEovzJBGVY1Na3mrTpunV2T63qxwFSksNqovTqL1nFPRr2YZc2puXH2ikU8UKTLkdTZWYp3CTA9W8Zdtm9uGo39p48ajRRKorMnztHsf3Q0CH@u/Q@OnCdHzsCB/9HR0RNmVhMPEsoDuCrVxI543Y9Uy/fPSgoWW19CRFI798@qGQXN@QQUeh3tEh94zSDCu7pxJkUZaCqXZdKCypcX5csyGYJPMDTKgQfhjRvAsiy0J7Ap@2rUJVwXl2SJDzRevjgLTNyQenF5hq0BaOYFf1Azw5//AH/r/1v/J89ZrFaPQ5Pr6mYnRlccf/H41c3VjXhW47GY@IjtwA8t4BuDXN1U0UiersBUi8Xr8ZsbbgfPWHyHA6xiHDtVCjzzCIU/EsRJ8fJH7B/2jXGL6wx3bw6Nz5@dTdLpeLnp7xaLY1PGNQ2Txst09sdms6bV//THtCfw/Th5ymXLZW2L8Q89q5fLWf9ru1AuF/yPzVisePuqpu9redBvstl4vFyGj/s@2DR8BmALANb/yAFU0zNaVO7LkavDI9otF8RELhLHFHHBEEvTptp4PkNULsn37sXEqXT3d@P37unF9PV1YDMcgpU2Z9VotC230UD7zPW13JBpvLyYg@904foaZFk07rixp3isB0QUUzT2sV6lOIuOC4TYBmempfQZFj3DM0YjN/bGGiZlnIbqyXHadT@ddtyz6E@//@1vn0UrFVmRyTarIQCMheV2dvLZajWfBXO@AJSSN6/4ARTdRFGL32ymZE4NJm9GI8JJK2zHuWyMojvUcOx@FQq4hxe7uolQtrNsLh4D6RoHPesmgj9urRWL3J5l87FCoih@lY04q4IOwH/YKs0kslvbWw/qjH6TZReK5PKVWdFuKldmCTv3bsotceITrv8y793LFIGmhXT5TGo0Hu2e7jYaFVmWsTqEB1qScJfwKJehG61RhueK9Rqmr34WjZbKD4g5tEKORaJl4U@JQi3BCkUig2R1cHEnpB0r3tX3s8e7e/unSX0HFBj9YHcvqZ88fxjR8DM3@ybnDH4f7@8@OnoOAZ493t892f/k8PP958/A3mOXs8uXt@I5e4dNS74v2QvpS/eNYZqGOTbNxuV4fPmafWlZDQvI2B9bluV0XeaZDdM0h@DNv8pwtyzP@PJLwx3Sxd796LvvfvTfvfvt77/77e@@@@0f/vSrH34X7t@F@/v8/f1/V8zh86df/c@/8@63fhss/xPcfwT3T3761a99i9/0/cdw/5eQ3R@LO@SP3xLA@qWffvWDH//0q1/@dbj/lbh//fb9Kz9Zfv/wO6tvDPeD31nv5/v/Hu7f47B8v9//LW6H71v@f4v7@@Vff/er/4H//1T80Pjb7371j/EhPv75r//pf3n37f@o64U//bfvvvv9d9/5wbvvfPvdd7737jv/VH/3a/9WS4cfv/Puh3/wV3/4e3/1h/8T/X@Xnr/3Pv93v/7P/@J/@4v/4y/@UNw/gfs/gOknf/EfgWf/9g9@hP8f/MHf/tGP8P@//Ou//YN/@be/9G/I8Bvc8P/8q3/Hn3/9K//5b37ze3/1k2/9zb/8yd/8xh/81f/5y//Xr/3nv/7vf/@v/8dvo@Vv/OSv/uiX/vLb3/3L7/yLv/z2Vyue3137/Oo97L/6R7B5fzzfB877pOtDbb76ufD5@1BjFgvwCTD4P3v3a78IPP6r/Ot/gC/4B07fCz7mXPjH92YfAOE3FwJFzNJ8xVDQC4kt0J63ikVROQTOOxTyp1/9ix8HUfziPNQ5N4jxe1gu59y@hyX63Y@@9e7H//Tdj37j3Y9@CWW3ki0md5OKtr43FZpbSu49/KHH/Pv4Q48Q/RdfwGOSoK5AJYFf7Avh4YsvvpAm1yloBKUfXIPtF2TFL8adwI0JJ99N2OP8y7Afbkz7xk20vg5HDWZN9GpvSDq98SFpCXwnNsAE@G5JuQx8EerosuWnJiHlNN8hImBxxwmNXkzgL2WLLAKBJpPEBNpEYEhMWAKcHiZYpVKhwJUJeYVPDDNh1QLD/kNo21QQOgTiYZKNAoKYPCQoELKSOGaNrcqEB0wgvCpBIOTQ6ljWdDlRqDyCCCuTRwxhIXAC@@pVpVqoTKoI7i2hABElHhJOCKySmFTfwneFYEI4KfLoLaBSqCQS1QJGiInktEo2KE4tR4mjtCcYpRvtGU0rvf@AsY9lrSDznvQNJBj3jc/EzPd9Gtu5D@5niS2RHPr7Rrq3iOAbFJWIhWcLRrbBwwsPAFdRVFVlcCsKYvMAnCccVIKihVciIbIV4PEe3MACMhjzIkH5m6APiD9S2frgK1GVeGo2NzelSFXOyEc0spCAdqN7XuLHGFxz5bzE5HxRRmuTZhzz1Jmbz6jhu/VoC54a/Pc3aCJwgpUJrc0odi9FGY@PfZzg94MHW@xjSD29Z3YSUxIZJ4vdu5jQnURC1iHWqpOQXoIMkoB9CdC1pE4qNJ6RkJJJxtRKBN0YtP8FamTxsiIlgPv1jIbf2BU9Ho8jEEJVk2oyKd4qvclCFQaVXMVb3USaU3cY0/VsGTTsMkMrFlaINWg5oeXbt28hs2gyQOkQ2jRMzAvQswVyBAu@nq3fn/qz0PVsUeINOqbl@TGoMTqHLM7iEouxrbjEp41yJIJhxqheKETRFIc8UWNb/jSRvCb5vVTUSRU6zxtbGYVc3HfcO2J7R0@e7D89HdbrTBJnzzfEodbrxGcMw@0@fcRnlevFPKIRqdUw5tOSjtJI2i@lEY/E4aPjw5MS4zQRORQLIMXL1AMpSFHUpMhw@GInIobSZTyxwJFP8FmapT@mFzMYYbUsRVomqsrAcPhnZemJ133oTKA1mZTlpJbHYeI49eEx6RtOqVR5q2W3JXjT95jhDjp8uR2UTpx7rO7sENGk6pVC3a5ohAzOS9WqmJPCNKl6sn8KAU6PmKanVQZtzavstp7NZXN6Jp/PbetaNl/M5nOFDNQG@XRO17ViNlssFLdvpOoXbKIirgqY@5W@aXdHvU2cCSKfpeUQPTZr6ST@9EwGngAxqeW26xsb/SsFETwjtrjCKT038HmlIAU@gotJH0nsI7CCC@LAeTpMTJI6PCqLmSq4sD3Gp6vIWg4Kd1w6A0bi4KRh@CrPfQ2hLEHbM3RLkY1vfnPEqlVo8ymHB1IERFaP@VM3FKut9lRiqvbYNcm1y1jb@tzCQy3UtuUN@8YUCmpalSI3NzcdgHR4gCN89MlDtPF50yKbJphvJob0/1//gNcO3/ilinPxHaNdwUVEtN0EFLf4VbvSdlp00E25U6nV6dyiclttOu2p6o2mIAZFNlaizb7TOo/6jhaeJIjr4iopI6U2ULiMnEajUommUtH7@nautJFyUyrtc8ViHSis9/X8Nlie2dw21gGbHNq8nLcqltqqj9QTYFoIp5f0fO5mR@z@VoU0IWpVRORK4FeyHdu8wVn0JaMDkviqxadKlWQ9V5DLtfLsezsvl@s3DwZm2zLYWRpnTl8tDZjPyze@P4jahOJGC3NiAzxtBddflNJn6fiKwGkIDCgTptKO2HCmSlN/aiA06nhkdq2@429FA7W2pOuKnlEymqJl8H@HQcf/@/vX4a/jE0JldOkUl2M9hewG4Wizx7gn7shhp45Dxx89NFsrfOz1DJrjtOc6nvf38PPQsM@50yOL74ESOH1q4L7n3sAa9Vb4eD4c4DIx0/1Hg7A/aAKCyIPcw0N4uH3HWeZhmz1/tiKVT4Jdx4AYfNsx8H58@Mmnp6H36f7u3qdSnj08evpo4ZUTnnLs8f7BafC5zV39oLkAxDf2Hz9e/BSvCFaj2CG3wXLbvkGTcJLkPWhE3BPGXH5mTKPxBV@/Y3nBpD2@UKsknfqLeqh8WE2TtfjKvYk04QvfhXKjbRclachs55Jtp1nb6fcNPPqtswGWPQMXK5hYXffphEKM@tJx@20oYuaG9ATXRRQ1PN8KkZA@BSCDcYtWmVojCbdRaeOhbNgB3MRzpcd48OEKS3ihFRpdq9sbsdGl43uQmobB4P7QC8Kb4Wu03mLE4yC7Wy79296liGSMjEihDAxbbtvje/e0Zy4wd7WQLpXO0jfAXZWHZrl5Xhqanjn0qvsT4DU2Zs@B@w0XhWRvM4UtUraZk/MtWS8dsGySqY2IsYV071qVGjsBNaU@PGYF7MVsGZksKK1Y1YOiRpMi/vo3fxd5dysFYiqiyTJO09zQJJXUO71YyBWKGb2QLBQL2ZyWz@WSmp4E7Xm7CApOWito@UKuqCUL2WImC/oSuOaK21KEz4ZJbRFIeJcArN3Co5h2SENUe1UpwkcC2JuYEWcRI/geM9mEMDIevguVDK4D27Iqsg6Ypxk0DgCiwVoscnCwlz44kOWH@IHjn3tpWW7jR66QTm8/lGWTXPZAp9Nl2eFhCrhuXR7xj3T64Z4sjzkA3PJNlnv4sZ/H1r8sW/ixt3twgPF08EPH8ODtnLvwj77/sQ3ebPzIZKj7QJZfB@DA3y6PKEuY7uMHxokuB9xlD9xk@RMfn3QaIBxzfxzCp35ad3dl@ZB/7O6iyx4lPMdR/Qw/dumSZch2LBey3AVDF2s7WW6CEUuHLLfA1JoaYIcHX@G@YPbIkOUpJxCSSJYn5NtoncvQABf2GM2nn35q9EZts8uvqcvfLUANXKzJeP@g@cknzW636U539z85Rpe9vU@NznTsNrtNEazZgMuBMOByPpguXoDjYaNh9Je6fAYu9oJLY9owEbeG8RpwElcXIxk09sBlD1yWDaJwaHANwGsTr4cDeD80muTiX@RC70mzKZeRUXFpP51eCWWGDpJMDoyW65Txe1LZYCwaiyantXy6XiYHNgANLV2@oWMrY3RaODZmQZe6mtYmlXS9Mqls63z8vROTzyZ6zpKTG4P7WhHUL@O@pmcTkxKuB3U6URZVtPsx7d7Wm9hTULMy2ZJ8dv@@Ite0@n1dK5Ty2y@3xrIcL@Hzfma79AbaWlFo6uEjXtuu3wedbhZkezthpPTS9na8fAPkGEHt2cRGZiMWuzSN83gc0cUmCSSBH5o5pXRa5U5skpxUOFZsGi9PKlqZb1nD0rdgtXF/tHFr5LgcYhfATe6nS3Qsp6wVCzLEn0rF4nGQTCRE4D2bWvPi66fnp6dfgMyCxp5oKj3jZ72Vxecnn@6p0HoSX7ivmXqAKrLjqnsoWOZc@LZbvtWpORmpn0IVCOqqb4cz9F2nr@5PoAGLerbv4O9Wo4o9RtTTT@fgoADmMeMCxzKtgrdbJsNt36w2MypVMBltaKKTuDPil1T5NqrVSqMy4CdrVoNQn/GjyWdgDj2Oe7DskoJf4ax14dCopG9m/p@OB@wh90QnBfvBGpWHUJunyzZud2ri5yabRCZStY07wj2sPLwal7CL5KZsVkw8gVSO4KLo@3ZlbHtGx3xmurjK@PBoE2oZnOsObQOTxTfZGZ1XuofK@I1SdZk9h0vMUKpN7FWYswx9IvlAM/@6T5grWoGBg5c30LKJvYyXX8OXu8libfUhNEay5XbsIWvEwSr9qvOqw3SWz5bpGKcYwTKSREE6CzReqX4GOg4HfF4qATKCE84BKMYEcK02ORjxoXVT7lZq6PkaHzuKLNcVpXZdl6qK8kKqQtEtTyNGxRs3ad9Qlm5qejpfnoCdtp0t91iz0nw5KbuVITSsWbkPuS96E/jCEqMMNARKAZw31yz27he/Fd9RchVuWSZg133QIxpqozKZZVWmUtOz@aSez2LnQz4Dt5bUMzrOD0/q6WJS16C2hlocwsO9Dd9ZuMEPVOa6hl0UsX5MZkxOpidpVUtqppYEoqdfWe1X8eR5DBQSIlo8OXL28QxUsEBGAualT3gb8YS@1Y@1HWbsKMTKIE3KlE4j2WNDCx4I59g0@tx/XGGZrVh/M4aeNk/Hw/1avVTanwy/Dk4x5fX9fGI7nXgTj5djIELjFc98LVXLUhWFD1FhuAGsLXpemDce1NIbkO4rpaHcQHaPNrVtvVQbb9YUDRKYvu7uyFW5ziDHbphQdlCocH1nprHM7BqoVeNpwkwr6mVJpTFuik6L6cVV6xPiEs6uEgCloRCISF0WO5P9hVaxaHRbj0bj0TJ20G7Iol8NpCA/mBjEcfSedl8GHUsuyUUdPcyEKa2lSYfVrBsJ28ssW5QiV9LN1c0ONDtTNNkJ1EG2QSZFrT6QIiXGQNc7E7s1pDYY@9A5VImd6kv@PsNJlgBXoo2FaqxOMxtMC9tK7HNcN3ifRQExwx3UdD1Tr@nbUAeCXPW96rpWxu7nCM7iVKtAee8K8NtJVHHK/WdsOjUSik/Ze4x1E5sSJTqySPbdym73eLfsf@1hp9eZJMtyOSpHrqKR6A38pAif56/zef4sEprpz2cJtkygz9sIyQu2d@V3qpRw4/uYUeLSoVaPv31q9a8KGYW3@0Fg3dxENlOUI2LidPmzV3oO8sh2/JnU0P4ZQY0A1Vsuh913kdSrofdNvZB5cnhkP3IPTH/KZLYhVyMsrSk4LblcErY5PpFSLhZ0WT9PRtiDSDnCzpWoVqLJ1mx4Uny5/bLw8snzo@dHB1LkbON6w8GuXeaThb21v/Z18BjNZKOMnVUik0q2LCazVKuKtqOz@1ALMDxduqPllfR1lbNvlRzyOri8@8Vfz052CvCtg4ZbgizMJfRqVdvSWTwyfPfV7@MC@Kv9z3cfs6hnTNnf/cmP9e2/@5N/TVNEojdlj7oOtyPgE41afjtydTW8urqBi7vlIvUIRyq7HQcz77PWIrPp3KWUYWxtJ7L6A7ucEn61bS0e8ZSI6JnfzkW8a@Gkpwvg5Hedk5WcxyyI7B9bOV17sINMoQWLP9hsHNX0isAVhSevrhmDj1a13e1aOplSKVZ6q7Cdt8oOe4tdz2@VDfaqUsWxSg2XjPj9q1vVahWhsGg1kdqKMj0HbrWbcj3BqH8WGoMvzS1762yeo882WLFog73pbYnO/bMtD1p2Wzb9zC3Pg0//y9z60mMyDj@kUu027QyyY7JcFfJ/KwXonMXf/eKv6Xr@7/7kV64b140voG4oFot5TY/8TPvZz8DDmrXKftOMuqJxUTEagiYdW3ESqtqC1iQej9th3L/fwMMmHQO1wera0F7HL@kCdSHKmgbfAKcdI29buJQxSZo1bU8RL0tSoIGS5ux2W0mCwbZwL2oom9KV9BE6QdXKKiAupY9moBieYt/vO62G1x@7Q5okHaNwWj3J7kEQiOEj3DFoQxw2TzJXATGV2rodlKPsEdVIK2ID0/Nw/yGoRaSPIMhjYHs64IoNDVwtjD4tG4S8il4IT3Jo1yDuOsTd5wEaZBuj1HMPScax44Fs0K6lj0AzICpYoDEwawc8lEGwfAQEgDTEBGCrznZYJs6urESiPNvc6AYnnPIz5sXyQQmDIbQ2roz1A5fRH1iBVo9nWCBfiBwG9Sxk6QPhMPhwZAXaBRicvlDloqXE7w0KYNG2HTFKGrt3b4ZVpWK144xShPDPrSH2SlE@2MtxBWB@i@rjdklOMjuRwMz@aJ7tgOIJQhe4TuH7RZVDQZmMnzeSBP/3ZlrkyIWsIocyJkDkFy8VLSAZBEay8zxssZ0K0/TtOAuQbwHuLUKKNjUKmolnk49V/Qvf8QYw/FnE3wdWwlPlQz19gm8Xl6oyqPbGuAknbljChYFYYsq3JEEpdjjyQwehIClWn3x3LBcaMTQc6u9vFMtocQw22w@K8KAppHqW4VzOXBxfFAp9M3gbuJOPiGeDuudbDmSoN3Rs2vqHtinAabLAESCjxA4qHO2xfYmbNou8ocBhjDzaPQU5HzGmrYzoHCwKi@OLTRdauj5tkszsqqw1aDO9yGLEaLTTix2Ai1MgQrhp4qZbrtPsmwNA6cQ0Ge5@45VSqS5oReMmbXfzxAK@6h1YUJXYXkocOZa6tM6t1CluOqk4HVChxeLhCCpSWPz4UKbYWqbvOOesb52bvAM3Nrf02mN6PglKaxIoO7uBsCXsK9YzSZYG5yT3Bfc2vLa5sZAMhd2ITeO33xltI9bAHL2mOsly8TixC8MO0Zeua0k0g72p52/eQFsQwLcaiFxTLNuuRHHFaLAfgSS2oajQDggqduIPY9Dk9LdvQCPo4uYF@FA0CesYEJotfyE0lmJI7UdUAVDZg5KFOzmN3BIu3wdM3HasBUVPCHibfcwyukTHuNDeGmIfDICBWV@Zhw5uEBTT4Y3akDEqX34DcgVK56ANbrhwVLAfhve5G820y9aMvdmGAIeVDsVVYbxY@B@50AeWDuRnSvoGOOYBwyWYbMTkBIBNyHGZgw7CLwbn3C6RLCmx25CSDCEIUgMUUhX88wZZaHdlCRweGh7f30/s@XR5eanS5mNj11JND3cc9vAQxdSwa4FO7KRG5mAoznax8LQvAXdmUvhG43i05v0JHWpZvDflb0nqeBUx8SAW7XhRrBwvcEPd7oA2LcHdQjxiqAOLNuNuxcRcCc5/ej155fNfCflPKURvEAhjCGaSnCZbSQCWbLbOk53Ldlk4XFCBBOCQi6Zvifv9uf7HwPNN1rAT@HBGNCnd/272z1tO30GdRObdq7OoeQp9n1P/U3wPrQkEss1Ltuu6xjRG7nH0jQwcm5Law6ZQ7ZMLGKGaYVd89zlrUpvW54JPguBQqQXjyC7uSCJdrQfKtyJE9wl3n4D7hLtPZpH60dYmda6SodUNJge5Hjey8n0imKnv54Zv2zdzIcigWDONg0Cf0zm7G7hbFQrt05t/QT5WfMYAnhgCwc1YqvbyrHZWtz3zcqueSHWB2WUiBOQ4gK7ViaaX7cCM1O9f9IeON2dl4/5lUCsJvNGq1RPcwHkF0xhkEDEGp5eFW051ByrvB@IKgUgwQEA9DBxRNdgdxax4OdjQkhyBcWryjMYcsZpApk7al3ASdqAucdJzwoYB1UOA0D5IEqAJLswvOXx/eV86vHDxgF3fr0JbYg9w65NoPQqUXCgqXNaUKZNCWCmKjyaQHdXVymJSfHfIitqCUyiZNyL/w@hvfDD6HSgXy7EnhuUVRlkKFxWciQUqhCguRFVWrYTyFTBIbRl904Waa5/rp6K2hmi2Un4zg8eDSfAu8Ti9WCjzW3GeP7RMSLblUsAK00oFkjit8GLJy4VPUk7wIJgngk19RhDhuQABGOmlwUwRbBIONqlUuOBgkxXBLkNITgjJCQ/CfU9WIFkXwaD1FJzDitlTB@0U533JAE/j1SioQUOZ4Zl6OFb9JW7LhCOZIs6ZzCEuEDyEKjbyWau@NPZaCOmQ0FoAgIx4C0CbH1VTkhYFnqYEX4GM4qT0ZRT/EmzAZQUwGIngMt@6MBYwGbWBQeGXE1QPQNmVEzVJ1nDOGf3S/JaTvqV/a7ct0/M@tXnLdHLh949iWUfKhgpoSPvQ0lkUyNiSeS5OH57TOSJ4qlvPAa2ueemw2BJlG@xT/sHFqWbfaaYGBs4PwQMsguOM4377AYdE2IOhMzJGTjZb4o0mi9huWfy8zWB1bQeaJuEtS0HXazumZ0dHkKktp2tbnpnEA5S5ym7SbAW@D7IU1pOF0fEkSfRB8mYsguZ8hapuo4FHajUaMc/sd@KlYMoofqrIntGohO1fMIXCg3gSQI@GMQePhh/F74aJu@uKYKdW6zx2NBSOUYhkl4EMa4H@D6490GCY58xajrTPJ6rSzVGMNsTuOQOnC1rf2FMlDL0A/nAGGxEyhkPCJckMbNKWQlssUymJtZJGXAT97IODss/0mBEPwuvzAOaIkWTuIo2Rsu6S6Boro@PB/PhOPhzfkzC@J@vxpVb4Is68aV7hjh8WdSY2gwAeZ2hk7kYDkw5yq30LnTlUAmvUq3iA90axTfOv2ojpLnjdFd7VDvBHMvjy4CtA/PNV9F@fgX7w/ffNPgPPGTyZgrwZ4LTAGO2D7vmDmzHwfhiPS5El0QWs/eg94wK/eErEAaoQoMaS4LJxi0IomENodnvBxtk@4Dt4HqdR3eJ7mltV4Y5LcHIvkuxcX51Fjxpts29MzXZM@EyG4PopPoYGG8mr90s4CjoSeg5v68Wg7ooHrlCNI9G5p9IKljGSF/H4arbiXqyAe6innDA8XE0/dL8lmrGLr8J7q6EdEI3idln2hYXdn8PpcMp3we3TVt2@HOX1D89JXAx9N0GADmI7kOQs2vg68XkcC5L0HjVC4FedTzJuUulDxP0fb@fhh5Ho7pRC5oYCVfxcluZ3dF@e49a6HA9xhc@TfNzo/VjyLqZ7b54LsRoHNhNhex9WhdyCjDMyWq1YGCK3WZtjjn1LJqAd9dPZK2qVxhKBGoQkSTeyqLlN@kVcwpbxIbyxw@lzeCPArjlqcIby04Z9WuJcCUYuA2MY0lqEDSjpACVERU5ygUbIl@SbwfvVTRBna2WcrVtxtubiDErAfJQhT1JrLkqRC5g967Kgb3ZGK6QzOmHbGV7rxDZctmO42FtxFbWiJSvJohfREgjkqBkt7cdAKEfb0dIjMnjR0gkZzqOlz8AwK1vR62jJLxbowYVPMjxAeyHC8bsVLe3F4jfSyDg3PT9eNVoK8hT83OefRBEgBaYbtEYcYrMdkcyRa0LFRkplkiHHeElsPlE/TJLuNPz5GQ201zs6Yh/nFnlmCabNVRqhGoPHA9WGv5fwkpJcErX5/tEBzWgKvGA0CWjjhcMQeFDDI9F5YcQRQ1ca0YA3IIhys7QcIxaqyd4THRE7cChl8nz8RD2V9IF2jNxr4Lk@i4QO5hDh/fyaB8Ez8P3wxMCr8LyFjh8dYYRjsvElaCFRX0XXJArzeh4XkfvhHKK@7nlPeFCn74XnEoENyXTQ4WhwDiMbOsN5JiFXnBlvhcNQpxwvlMi9C8FIKoiSucKZrEXKUDCEC398XXJC4RC1ORGEjrV0nZeyoF4gWYxOM1kX0lR54QMUQjIHSrjZOqdDTx4JI/nj4iZJdcWqasgPy6MkyTUvJiGwiru6jI0Rjz1ovO7jXi8f1nz1Q06wryWGAEIhg1i4fHU@QH93uP7uK9Q@ERYiWKZYL69Kb6vXa2vZBcz7s2hvZyA6Jtmj@FLlKIhhRnJoHYQ083W8dkvFxykfXMnnkQbQF7R9n2xBm@AOui22LTgs1BLci3nLcx0sz/XVhLqtkfQvVF9pUTEmAYcnPMB0lrT1uPKEL8tidKH@baP/wRnszmdwOPMQHiXAXSA5L@Xu2KZZLrOyDWKb26BI1UqMC3IaLg2yeWYJ4p6GboNhW7A4ahw/Onr6@BtQ6W5vb8dFHT2d4YelFvtag3qcQ6YJ1EF9sKTZoifxHAMc7MbueDoUd@PMlm/JEi6sQRkwIBaf/UQZjwtZFpLnC2UXwnG/IYoKWOezYmDMSSVUdQyssi1B1xEQxBzFtgwBxFdvgd5Jaq3Facf@RgMPQm00qPpqNHDyUqMhajHMGn9EPP6zyEZq7Ll0EBs/buJSkmgxPHt0xF58unvKTj/dZwfP9z5j3zh6zl7sPj3FRc3Pnj98fLjH4N5/erLPpLnpkXg0DzYoga6PzJaJ56LhllhZRpD3nOGUy53YXpzbnxgD9qnTMnGYasczBg96/EO1zVGVh9qH5ugU@zAtOn5pYI1wvgWdHQTNWFRu2rTyDuf7M/DbhDbtANu8A6dtdSzwK2Hbd2iZnr8AjPUtyEGQt/4i0SRXkvCYIJo6RAd64QysSwhugH8cuwEwBp9/RWfNWh4PYLZVJggXXB9MwdP94ycnDJfN7x09fXR4enj09IQdHB3D57NvHD79BOh5eHJ6fPjwOTqRxydHjw4PDvd2yYIjkFYZLlz/cuyN1qKgoneiSuscR77pSOHga77XGzV4dmnQGkSPRcc2Sh/L6FtvzHa0LI09VF9w3SMNFbDY5u7xJ59Dnc/M1zjC6Q8F0/wD@blHx1VtptkOxQaFpQrlrSyKK1R7ihan8YjBlOHu9WaZ1qjHyJxkPnCaxNO2TCbv4RwV7PvmS9mpLPugIaINgI2g/AkrFUanTkSjyR0CWYXYWn0Ht8PjsfFJhOIDgz7wp5qUJaKYmCuDQHG9wqGN/UFaObAAvgcLXUQ7crkHlgksuAeW5Raoih7i3BGWEz7Go6MximeW5xZfDoYHNCzMtgOLhwa1YgsCJ55vlKUGC07twYX9fTpbhPfy0JlnhteyLArikX88d6Pf5wXD5Cc@gUzkQ4k0tw18yiBsOjjUIKa98QMP0RW4AecJGZ2Rx2KVuMpOcXKQaVv8VJdu37D5FKjZ1B3iPVbArVsqYpqtFZyGQitAhg4xIJ7ENI9HEO6R0ArN9w0HIR/eitEQcyTpRDJ/CtpdCDy8hcDPAwYAKXMtnRbVVLTUFME4HcHKMc8BjsR@27dh/8DO7XHLnAsgZm3FvrTevIkLIifn2kn@PEXCDrLojemCWklDmR3HhTJOYpXOj0Ap2Oo5w5HF8zA2nwIacaJqDnxjxQaxvapU52JDOizGaDt2KNImcPGKWJvAlO8TK3E8HzsPxNfsMEHgfKiE@bw7RMdo4pG6s7GzJA4iXZrY/QKKMI2VY@fndESYcP1TmsmOtwzPIytUqo8enilvXyXxUDIuFvg5gP6kQ7yBMTEuKB40zkcTFl3Uu0RJ8w@T8cZNDC3m4AlpiaXcBwbtwJ4F7boHjXLgxqcb37bHBTKL9mR5fV3hoRSUTOJoSK8Xm0m3JKv5USYpTJ2JKSAh2QnIgqyP@TZJghnI6we4FAZzoQwUsVGOYLt94agWIUL81DXHHZAs4sQ8kd0B/Dir0oyK2QGiuLIlnB@pl7GHlUQ1nppNKGEhcsZ8EZ30IWvxeGhaCtVXt8A9Wg8O5Pf7gyusxY5XDx8E7dFaaB@Em5JYDYtXSyFY7w/27RqwvHL7ucBC2pOrAfNK8ja0gNMD5kxuRoLZtOtjfHUr76jsARise7EHJQAaim1s0xC1v/lsjAeIh8HMFKKT00f7x8dM5u0TCAtyD5sMbSEGEfYGezabbWvZJOzUQGkKGsuB8uTbzM1o8691hXkp8VaICqGDJAU9AmExOyq3Y0241BM1C6kQNPueBKJPuXnsrnwZ5NUE4BtoAwKys0wLJVBamswIr3wsLzwJXNAtyXXj8Bx@mmHN6248h86dhgGF5wQZXVxZsjz/XnD9uOTHwxUs8/WYEtwGTRrqG2gnnEDEQ/CoqvM5uCZb/CzFSfZcwY74tMOJX@l5Dfvvz1DESFwJ57pwSKwL5VigxvXjTV/NoQmJWA0YONNTOPIZzeDgi3iy2QlnaHxW6cXmqyBQMvFksgdhroDg9ZtycFR2bFZPVgKFPFzWNgmbmo9lHXtnBezyak8f41zo/KJ4WIwKpO3aqJR/mKh4LTEXk0/zpYnxHQFyPpfL3AV7MRV@cOXvC5vXIYvyczQYQvt@BtKbetS9D5x7@DTpu88YYA3p@NR6v8AsBARVZ0mdMpd2qozC@AEuvF8IkMFtoPGwt8VY42yygNty6LxGCkMnL7fSECrCQUJ5qblF/Zv10aFAvjO@jQ@Pjxc29IRTB29wVv4Tx/XM2aq80E4rIStcvzpvZ7quTd74eqYBQonRMqa1i@1otR2f8MpThY403hZOSUesTuLTbpN@XwNFQt2LKp7viL175cXuPUUrh5N6cPh4n23RVnidub5I2ZXjIdmzYdnrECAZTP0SWH3QGr6PvRLcgEPSBwlkotV8MaJN/E7ciCKgNdfoIA4xLVTIVm0x9ztey7Bx24@k/LHH5OQ9CEi9sPtHB/FlPevp8lx4QM4b2jEIlZQVVaagYIcdughpHgTPTbQPVVi4UsOfKbnmVG4jpRXS@aJEqbOTo@SgVqwnt1oVmUHla9gDb@xets@7Tu@iw/ps@GVz0pq@ec1YLssyEJd@j2@DquUrKdpDchueBVZME@cKBO/Tlq5nMmMqHRqDA8ts1g4vb7A4GajRXMIVEgtcyrYGPhfiErtRZVDL1yt2JV0e1Ox6GRf5jRKVUUJLxNDiHtSiIGP4yHxtVMc6NdzratoXDA@IpCO9xNIQRktDwOaJ4VrO492nn8z1xqECgF1gYq43dajzsx0/wtlsuPZEtc3LmOgmSzLkWAkVJOkjWhWk4Zp26k/G7pi2BZhBriRBm/Um9JzGpY/S6ng4cshFRKQga7Fr61r6yF/GlKYeBfBSs@o@OjsEZ@YnhgND3HbKZ1ErGlfXNFw7GQ@BqGFIEofymSzjmkJEVKzlqtUlTzWNVg@RwMNMrykY29mho02B1TyVevFwKofh0oKJdB2NOAACryGNNmAUpLl7tOxDguTjt4YGbkN9VCNaJ0MT5CXSFNEFp3@zK1rfROF3gACc8B9xnUsVXZz/b3FXt9VGkqSvXU@RlrBRgX6xwW6E5BYgbPVi8CCwmwNYLaSSrG0h0SoBUtvsmd2LfYHd@32EfZV5h7nap5iNLyIzK0sImz4@Z5oLVFWZGRkZGZF/8ZN65UULSfEd5MMFxCOLb/yhZoBbpXTKIzQWsKW@UgScLcWZRqhWk4m@P7oBOYVW9KdbkCnw251m2Py@ZGeSsJ5av4WgJXcpJ5Xx04@KpZxiGVPMZHZI8eib1MBJF22P3gYkVlO1FfT7hLTQ4lFEDjyyf6@uf9nWH56gzjOLvKRn7qRnYulZSRekolxZmuCjTOtupkTyc5TvViWibOk7dZUUL16y1NOtLC1JorzFr@UNs@NhoxdlLtuuFK60CRuxhIyT8nFO70vK41gZy@A2/UTSNX@v6J63WMby/hivH7@e7qCAjWe1rckMl2YHvf4rmbRsCtgsQdRUSoqjv5ntRCi1D6YeTmgFh3N@FttyKYKyXDAjDstMorzxYyKrFxmvUrNoiBfjHcGaIyMOlbjOZSbchB0WqR5OfuyAYJhgNGUkt2wKT3XhqQMWuR6basUL8o6AU9NmRbwEv8gv@GeEPY6cyZecn/hIMJ9I48W7OU4gHnQfJ@aTKT6awF1EPupGfWUWieqezkKcP0jsOafAts5AfLA7OAZ/bMcJd6AwI8UdutsUTekoQ8Gw731diMRb7x@5Je91k9bYl/1goirYZjTZC8uLObgj7myIyE4ciya8urzsQ@vIC74bdqHWgUJWVqFuiSA6M3vWq8GyR/Kn8aQd0qlQVu0D8g0MRKKE8KqLm9yh2EE8JxpaceLSG2e9ymAqBxokM89WxM08UFehaE1pt991kZCeE@kBpcPLZivIerRGC2n140lTOyLf@jwdfiOIMEZT2rrn/eWq1/p16zX0uS8K@WcFh2TXWh2czz57HjlYEZFMwkqelrGrheee5@iGW6IbzgBgWu1ion9PvBlcB4NB4FVoxuCMIS1aw2B0HbSznncQWCUw4IKVoZmEH/bwatSSwx1adDWJGeElHKZFHUYchl/Mz6IubrGuLO1BaRVpm6mrr3ttENB4nHSG0A6zwgJhAoQeKHQRjIkoS76Ko8S6Z40Lr10ucBBF1ECcE0c3YckwGI57LeoZPsny@gRK1CBRZYP2DCZUX6vfhHNwdh4CcI@JKGAQMKqkr@HgaaX5H8JB6YYZHXvT9EyORr8hywqJezDq0egbEZh7hYs5uFMHH76p1VV9f@fwQ@Wgquj53cH@@9p2dVttHrOOG4pyDmyr3uzv0uhitemiNd@nD4lKnUomOMGr7B2r6s/vDqr1uto/ULW373ZrBI3AH1T2DmvVelrV9rZ2j7ZZ@04Q1N7@odqtva0dUrbD/TTXaop5UTm1v6PeVg@23tBrZbO2Wzs85hp3aod7qAxa/Yp6Vzk4rG0d7VYO1Lujg3f79apCw7ztWn1rt1J7W93OUv1Up6q@r@4dqvqbyu7uTEP3P@xVDxQbCTit3KwSlpVN2sKiJm7ndu2gunWIBkVPW0Q8QnA3rervqls1PFR/rlJzKgfHaQ20Xv3LEWWiRLVdeVt5TY3zUt@gCvXL1tFBFfGPQIn60Wb9sHZ4dFhVr/f3t5nW9erB@9pWtV5U3u5@nQl2VK@mFS4L46oJBlGL0ul586heY7rV9g5pzjh6B3sHnzr5AxGGsKxQ0W0mMMwg0Foi0v7BMaCCDtwBafXhTZW@H4CmTK0KqACLiq1DNxtVSEQ8dJup9qqvd2uvq3tbVSTvA8yHWr3qU4fV6shQg0HGMbEOVXrErUY/EV7ySMzqGc5Nc3eq2o6qbL@vAXOdmzigXtPcwmTbeqNpnkXEXOcQpTfEmUHzwj1Y6dz9dB0gAOXdE5n5ZzQ2YtLW/naVZmQdrCoRJRzRrPNyJpSSm0YzjU2k11jImnZwftVt9AadIXxMbTE5@LgIu2nceeLj6odT7ytXS@jzFS6QTDYa7ysN2ujWGw0//ZCSMTS@VUIfg38tl6/biJj42Hnj4Gd9Xei@ESNU@alWdLKhHhQQyCnUfyqmb82LwFe5XDvQxeC8D8Dm6CgUtcknqFJoaGRnR9xPEVXJJxP83tPswAVTBny21cA5KSwjOdMwpH@DL9GLTA7OBxqd5bgrl8MmltHo/R6YaqQSDonA/3REgl6Hq8yGQfBrN5V3q8OeP9sdDtsp3zdlOO@Y9oHdlP@N4udBd6Z4ZrY8I8tqZx1GPzT7bl7CWP2zJpnS/ZIdcctS@NcY849vsJGYDzg15ar4sFofWqaeSnFYJKWVDm0B9wruZKz53lZ@rn3Abi6/8rw48/2N/S6yBXtBBKqlCe@Ey53xz5szyUACxrE4iCQ9HSEjl3PKGHsTm/mGMn5CJr5ngOfqTwHP60QSWsheNftunZiNR72Jiz2Nw68PKm83j3Z2aOgEts9frr5YK3o27NbPafk9Rj0c6ZWjjl3SPE7rNE5ypGSLFj4sKU687Yj9mYFzOWREkHXTafwRcR6s3UbckgkDGZob4rKWAUz0EgHokFAcgOOxZ/h1rmRqBkjFmuqjNRfNCS/xm7RWYh7Qxiz9KffaBP8A24q/EXHbIM1AmsU4vi5xLu0ueNxL7BhTUd7ccOAeZMkmDB9LGDdLAz7qYvtZeNfym@ZtpxdDMWWEvHK3c0lC4vEsFsrYVQxEst9xnBF9AMzRw@jLz5rf6PFYB7jjcHfNcFwZ14mMO7Ykzqmjw2jd6BMN@axcoi56@tTWtKFwyu9rpFj29HGyDQziSAOjcgajwpKaAVy0cURmq2QL2B8XffVZOBXBOwCnqDlWvxPnzmuOhlI08UP0u4lKoQSWDXIiVLuxdXgmy7GNY2HIGSPTd9GD4f@JNJkDf4N2nAQ9opYTBPBBlGSoQivavjJRejdG0eBoNyJqup@OIzC3bsd8sg3T2puJ@NcQCXTvTM2HYw572EnNIQCYHAcbrvxak7RPTdo6/ZjwdXHoSQati8uU0nOFmSruwM2snaV52ZU2uhW8@MqXsyanwl0qqn6Ujds5Sz1tmWa28upJmBBwvon/kVviAxAr8Myln8RqdZaz8lrKzDigQy05E07bRkyiZentvVq7JeWEyIyN/VrzZQhFoMvA5247@faPoRLz3HjERZ6J1SFHwUNIcGyTMfnokHXnbIjZDwDnSZsPQ3BByPgGE0RfoHOovgiaSj1hQxFUElkdRnEGMdz6WSItT6s3Fns@mQSHWuyPBhKsPpBTLZMjKwE@NIauu3xWvW1OCeX@w5otLJZbqg/TsF1EZXIsocvjMpTWcDiipWMT7SYc072pn1Uf9KFDMAivRjp@Ic1nvZE@kTCLfqoGyybZvfM0IzHcGbWwN4a3QjvL/MFNughgISrhSSaZNZUi5jU8WjaHjr3JckGlNqKUDaIJhyVlIm6oNfXli@QSguqQoQFTsBfazQXbbHI90DtY8bsZjn7F3I8l0KAdtG1kUgcknwVKJ9UGHOOxNZamXw5DPtGgrsAJiKVEQQ7SrKEqzdEvNDtpu6ZEFB0TsUu5JX@8HsukxlqKKooYV9dOzLeWoc4ElVZ0aFAbLLSwssqozNtw3d67GeNooXG1tUqcDuyQsi6LiNITs3TEk4yb9ukYT/qQv/QkhPTQF@i49RIUCGPNCr3q3XGO8YNNwYdeMGq7Z6K0kmk3L3H8xluf4YB50Rwd6rB/reY4DKa0A2jlepMcw2ikfhp@GjS2hv1mtzfsNWmfhhjuExnx8DjlR3RYdzS8CfmeH05oO5na0@hZ4stIGDa8W71k0QnNFY6Dy5RrpjAeTSufJEwEn5zDCDC6dJH5@3I2Rpot83w1KuTF/U/ZHq/gF@8t@6wwr7Bo9AFAD3DlGQsK8SEds2OS43xavJPh/GsZHBzPVUY1/Xss9mIY/0AkYjVMDGODzB2zBLcR2Jndi/FJe5JucwzCEQItBdsBrqUJU/w53cT1tjSKvIKlwLoqvMw7RUWLMkEcQjxM7yf3yos/GXtC4DvQLzybxy3zGIGHuI6JthTKfkVHGSVc2Dywx2M0j8Q0ivW6NAv1Y0Abk1mo8eTpfdRgyx9aFOkwe3e4EhKZoo0Pro5LNWjIaUx9TCqLatHnuB1YglTGqfz9DBt8y36WhR9KXDk5w8C0pSGnHKTvI1WLqISbPGfMa12UJabytyVmZeWhvTZDwNI8kzPnxtpUwqxc2AOlJ/Mr1FrDEQ3GiRnqaVOPxXA8vFx8IPXuHTvmRmabR@uW73/TEFiYrUST5VKbSVua4nFa9GbxmWGaOMXY0ox4CNtXfrZsPkvESakBeSs1pt@gw300i@ym7KRi@7stso9J8RoWvWaisSLFuCNIadF@P2lQwxv3jyAapmyvGjxiNDBkNKby6ICaIZOl0sMpxNyncZ@hR5soh3rbRDu3f@4l6qyRnAl5apJiQS5BTwRuh9MmjUuXHRhfIEycrHDtIGUXnJP0lFV5hcw5ggwjQQBiVRxkonMoOcGNOmuGj/h2gE6qAWuhAkYieiq7Fg426L8lGEfl14c72uKhMc0UzooCaWIh0a6Cc30NkvE3p9eTxoSh3CEFifgcUtgW3RmbPj28Vd/bFspHEKQ0J2tL33wajfHVMmFD/9ykxgRr4KgqXTImUXFBaPDQQLJAu5RuP5DtKlZ/vZFwPKwbtBjRBkI@p/CzrEsgnPda3lIbRSbtKbL4mtwibb7KlKVIxFDyDvJrUZSlLm9cCUAgGFP5UoEgIKwpYw@lAIfecTkvhqjuIypYKkAs6SNHRY3sPOekg6g6w/NVJ0d@Xo4fXBiZuUBoYTE/T4QIrVnmZ4mg0EQ3Fxcnx4v57Yly0ILY8L5QnLpC90qchrbnhID0yNjaEeWkoNJ5zcGc@HzVjyVa/ubUH/JOan42lehjMTzJFGZTX@ZjqbFqV1biRWMliR6@W2sskUjhuwjbUeH7/tg1xQ15bm1CnU1GbJWh7bMH2ErdYN@W/ddQbbBTtlljGHiuZ7jZfjXkipVYUPavB2BXOu5/8fsbawxTDSL6qgAOS2d8XVKyH@QFawIzPVqFja4JtGfjE5gt7bCj3h/u7MSivp5PjZ3RRTBazefz4OFzN/a9Ma3GSVJvmIvnznWu@v3c5c1Po/fnOR76caF9Pxyumw10QD1CMhFmh6OuXAwBHCgrcme0Hyu2@ledjnsDAxSU6DvqNcmpgyEonn961ubl/SGf/zBIPb/@ggaifb8oK3w3TVlnaihGC0WlYRF8nTDKMyIPPnRgnm0VVQwM47IxZqJpyy@VP2MCwcUm3Fkcvdj/HFknJ94E/f4wrT7gomAECnh0O1tgZ8ctkJcsUDCyc@9VyOFo0yq47vUdt2JkcVkd4My8ZK6ZMGHhERr/IOhWJ5epxMnHBM0q1ORlNHMZ4anTKtFN@DpW/APACh8S2g/KfdG8TLWYTrOZaabXAhw9EUbPCum5W59YFp@PxDTNvp0bRJ2PbpZjNVDTfV4KmFD23L3cknuyW@ImTieFDmiYFxgaJ4RceVgJeJr9eaPi9bjTedigyLcASMf@0wdEVgGwBGrxI3oiiPa/ZEisd2biicj6Bnd13B13UKCBAp73pFX67SZVqVTUwuXysqpUNukhk1GVzYraxofNTbVN75t4f1paWV0typi77X@mj5vm463aJBh8wLnc@jTapldKK8FtDMba6OKFXGkhXVxolDbKxTB3UtmEVz89/f3f//Pv//FfuYp@@R@8bPLLyUebKZvN5hZanxee3hbxfrJ9trhwfrJwebbYLYLL/sFBw4e1caYZWY9mR@deUmYB5yubkZptNgef0UWVudTvojn6lUaXdZVshbmk/hrKxVE8xiZbgfM9gBvlOe3gzZ0Dszt5QiJJQKc4jafeaQWwv6P5hihJuMAMVMqLasWc2yMajM1glSpJHYiHl6zXAVxaokAKcMWlGSvTG4TBAAfg17zkleZ5XpN@e@OG5t/cx7dhd3M4UUunKbWUV0tptZRI8E9h7Qf66i/kenDOlWy0G0gk0pQSaRZgZajCHq/zePvAV@3MkNvzFvjGHkAyUSo4szjBpe3mj31l5L61sOs9wp2ZSk5IWMeEIsnPC4Nb6pbPlOM2EfO04YVCQ29iuDJHoWL7FyugZih2AFHNF0KQ9SFVCUUfOyTjKWe@6L72@DIhBgyyHrzeYbnHB5qLFgba5Dm2lcItR2w9L18xNxbFF5rRRorUHyHA@hTZTebZkXAxueiJkbfTSm6mOGG77dPMJ6YO02BsTNOl0L8phwnEmNsl3MJAu7VoO27RrqhEz2pXnKoSs6bfynOKXFz1x71L7a3AtUOgPtvabkWS0KMMSOBIyP71uxLG5wQmUNRMt8hdWVPVHqLpIgkD7ZlOHexnRXHkECH3MUWy/WVGtv0cO4kYdhAeYKSsJV@n2euHOujKiIndbY7OcTlgs8P3qY1FbcbHebgldQbjYccinWXIbHEeyTM1JXk5anYvmmmV3BsejprTGk1btPIZt7I@tRARmIAEhE9XPa95BmFpke4SpohtChsO4e6C/lTfjiZ9m7AuJ@hSIwo66gqEIMZOTMngS6yvZugYcfUf6AQX5TuDt1VG6iGWR14YGmlICddrhsXsjuh4pgZXdqzgJDxB1Uqm4QVd6AoT7QXrfWkk7yNEgK47oZ0AtSfC2g@oH7NTNxg0Y5PTZd8zfv65opJ5EfLMN1GKMZJnLj4tRBfeAStaR36MB4GQuclEM/IepVKPTkN9m1vSnUc4xrc1xc81Vc/eP8f3l7FjiDoa9GSwnJmhoiswsqrGhv8EodNvdgm/6U1zClY8TaZePc75Jx9PB2dLqdPBl9PffcZED8lmls2opNZlmxFLywrNjLl07NUYpYUm0uDpIJ7hdKDEhcUhASGSS518zJ19yRFCp0lcO3@aFILEugyY5L5eXw7gc3fQTMaxyCW9R/6Sbzo/9argK5pb@Rd9KB98@SUszKaST@lpnzPqECh20/3tSjxOwtzLlfzzlcJz2gl1g0lmFFxhvs2EV@fBhJYSIbazNPWc/h7jhhghbidhs0gfJ9ROudVEXE9C7aOkh1At5lyPZ9mKymSFJyg/UZmjpcLDxbd5mtA9wkQwrYjlTF4OBSWWgw73pTB/hsML1NMMMa7NOocIR8LIQExE@AQ1A8jm7pX7ONQ34rLIbk5ZtYXQrQyEujeXdGaLwXCQ0Ys1P7tYxCIaTjP9l/mX@VkZvSOiMQld0IupxceqUH714m//vf9bcpwsr@Q@jOh3nPwtufYyKY/0QG/PzNt1spzcQLa12@Q0R3tgenzxt/@l8uWfCA5Sphv0r7xqYK1Nk@VMiYt8SZbX6KGwskL1/t9f/0ptWJAdG65iXWikFSNWNBTZag6Ydyld1dBK2ZYuRsMK@2UBhhgY0t6cXmAXNVl5medTuqQ2qrgOdOArY46ip3i2yxqzpZCcZBhzCloZSYESKsgISGNB0VGO6Yax2gDzRmiqX55k10LaAfyirTlsldZy40kIi6EF2RZRB6akRtrPy0M5/yphrTvWE8akpGiWkNja6bH25bPi/wM)

Joy on TIO segfaults on polyglot because lines are too long. I recompile it in the test driver with increased `INPLINEMAX`.

Joy has `#` line comments and `(**)` block comments (not used).

Joy code is on line 23:

```
[ ' "…"]298 .quit._…
```

`[]` is a list, `'␠` is a char. Unlambda and dc code is hidden inside a string. When interpreter encounters the first dot it starts
executing the subprogram. List and number literals just push themselves to the stack. After that top of the stack is printed because `autoput` flag
is `1` by default, see [`usrlib.joy`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxREE/v6BEPyu/Ur@0uCgnM0kPyPz/HwA).

In Retina 1 [dot](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#global-flags) disables [implicit output](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#implicit-output),
so using [explicit output](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#output----): `` ;K`250 ``. Not using `>` or `\` because it breaks Retina 0.
The dots in Unlambda code didn't disable implicit output in the previous answers because they were to the right of the first unescaped backtick, which was the second backtick
of Unlambda code. Now Unlambda backticks are hidden inside a string in Retina 1, the first (and only) unescaped backtick is `` \` `` (not `` [` ``).

Answer (score 5):

## 299. Wierd (John's), 13960 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::   _@_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>> xxxxxxxxx          [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      # ????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~* __+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@)++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
# 
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:peseps>Ex Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:F 4, ._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8ogr ca34* 16  prstd   
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4@ZbnRyQLvAJAoAqowoN4EJAoiryXfSVRTVJXty8IQQWgAJQIVEFVAAmIoqK7Z7fXPfbOent6HO22x7e7ZzxrrydivBM76/aOPRNhf51wzCf/APmxseHYcP@D3nNOZhUKIABKbTtiPyxIoLLycfLkyZMnz8ln0/B6P/95BD/sidOfdvvOiI1Mb8TarnVhuiq7P2X3DMvL6RlJwli7bnc8MO2RV5IiTGPMGxnuiPUNuzs2uiaLgK/OZu8dqz8y3STzTJM1zb5zCeEZxmzzkh3aLasNkNjIOTdt67XpQliWsQdm/83gzYi1nMHAsNseG7qWPaLQHGNPDHjpjFvnzGh6I9dojSzHhqA8Y0/tvjFotg1G0YeuyRNtMwDVOqc08yEFxh45rmdCDk7L9DwHPYvgabiW83D38ScL8bU0@8QApIZ9c7KQvaaxZ5bpthdT6Ozz04ODRd8M@0xxbHZwEyUty3bHI@dwtAg/x3a7pm0wXS2q@mJgHog5MvuFdCE9FwRhB5YLtWmIWivNasYeD5qmC8QXVXhpjXoqJDh1OMGZY/enzJwAMMCxA9HMEbOwtlguncaY8H9ithy7PQMPXibAAbjmYDiaMoXZjuABCHJc5g2Nlqm0zb41sEZmm/UtwM7pCGw8BhXOzs3ppeNCxSucFQkRb2i2rI6FSUQJPAmZ7YHZHHeZMx4Nx4Cex9qWZzT7EK05ZW2zY4z7oyRrQhgQj/wve6YtULLsLpbj2cwHIdjQBDj2mxrQxur3GaBzjuhg1h7bwYBL9MeoTZOwNNsIan9GLoBk9D2/9PMZz2WD6Z64Ttc1BsCobZNo8PnhE@a1HBfe4ItxeStYB6ZljNjODovuP34QZdWAjKrblAKSVtgVYyziB7ILoz82PTYwppC3PYLGxRyqPz@FBNFZdCNaYtFMhulpls2yLDS2AtNzaQZNoggOaLV6RoNvnukFltWA73PRJObTcY2u1Tc5lK7T7yCgbeRYPcd0@E1no0ke2qI8tlmmwPLbbDvHtuG3yIo6ZIIQs0wr5uCbhy9AKAIGGnwzWZ5TwBbITlAEtsc6xsDqTzn04RDBt1hOY9sAEdDUALJeAAhFHSHMf8LwRj0gbM@4AJBK3zpHcWEGEgNrKwWP1NZWikQWykaepdcz@33MFQgFJMoV2DbkmodCZyFnoKNe0P3Cd3tUfMJrOw1fwHEbSlwA8qaBUmkk1TZ84R3EkA7yRgfhooO80DXw18GdQagQLw9heairfEBavU20BekKaTUkJgoUDWkAyRhUXSbLoPKyUL0ZrN5chgGegMB2noFMKWiskGWFbQbkKqYZkF4DZLDuNZBlGiChITCoUg3qVANENGAWDYBqmRyTQnTVMhgOaTOQFkigZSFNFtxQL1oev5AOKl6DLDXIU9eLM9YC3PQcFDKXIZ7T81B52xAGxNIBVx24RQds9QKEY9oCEK6ALLntE8LoD3sG0gJqABkZWA0IkgOcCDbEB7e@neEsRbGb5shqSdcStCreA4Ylji89UAKANGEGww4UGHDGPbFAAsZBIM0Lq7Fn9oGLQIa0DHAj20JrR8nhw7FGKspZ6KZM5wI7Umr@c9l4JCKaLvaiIK/apusyjAudrZckYeKNm575aox97QyvDkgnEwRrx7D6AQLUdIwR9QPwjHqQ33Qe7Y7rDKh9DVBY9B1nuELsgmi6RECfOpfmDPWZ5DKGwz7Ic/A3gRBjow/IXBqkD5C6EM6VIwSJMF2rZwFAygrkquWaLaK9KDqkzoAEnkexxPTqnQxCuR/qFjJs6IBQ9TCNPe73S9DdmS2Wqaba5kUKfXjXMd9lIA5@ZwL9oQDRNKAvp84UsQgg3dFV6qZO/Zr1nMF80bh4OQyK3rOwC@hfGlOovQ5IFnNiDEDjYNit29BxD4BjeA1iTXi84zlkbceOjgIoly50r1DooCQAsk80GVkDE/QxB5JgjWcJaRRuhFlzCqxM1MqqpI5xTBYIpUqLhOIe2ZAHbyzQsbXHLaQa5m3ZxEHQIXjUW1UBLlc6VXRAk3NNo82joXaBGIX0I@jtTCC6UAVaBAg1FNP2QNvxVGahWggM33U6wGPURYOqAUln@bSo7FjywGuitlSJKI18MzjvM4u1hkMG/qCfAFoH6QL0sc5Li72GwH7PY/3W2HWnbDKECrAGEGvUcjodYNrX5rAHINigzVrTFrRKKCUyjdR2SAK1hgtFDt42TYhjm1DsvSffYF0TqA09cgcwJU6fFWA4pCIQKQyb99a2AZTCIrSGUyILgAlSdBxHRf@2Y3rEI6DNBC0eM/PMLrUIaF6dmQwaoPYBzAkagQ0sCwJHtCqEjxlKSwuDWYnK/8S0ocW0gBmhrUP1oT66yzqg@4c6a1TujFbLHI4EezgkxSw7pNAcHaBCQ76KAKZ6PWnzHuhicxhIEFXyOSfUgxvnJFxR0Sc9y0ARKwwM6NNtM1BhGRco/emN7CHGxULu8guMM4fBC3kFDkNqCajdkWwYj1CCoFC0Wj0UgSMUMqRlQCNzxzeLD37h7N0BUzpB3oiNBtJGUlOBF@KxGoYC3/5NQOqwj7Cqcx4Ydc7jFtCGN1gC2QmQ7LfDvmrKUEEW3gZ04NjOEqhAzAAuRpkPobogZjxBqWH0A2ak5uLN1RHK6Znti/0XdJ3DoeNCy@BCZ4qSjFdZiLscbqfEgi4iDnbzfI8KPUUU@/nRiNtcwz7YQdTEsKWCPmmApAAhxi0AkHkOzzGEMLV6giXwuySJz5kJulDbNlElNdwpBwLFg14ZMpoyy3VBDF5g38C7Hr8PUYlPoSsw2m2UrEgOaveLmavI0XvjpjVZNDNa6Km@9KQLw2UdtDBc0DWgEcWiHS8aL5M/pQwFySlnOEpRUv4rQ0SKpEKVxzpgtEBHcACC5mRqt2LyXBOTk0wejzoFOQ4OTMhVM/Y1YzhaxO4l@CHTDM6hXdNbmXWh11YU@FXQjzDBgJSKAYYL6gU0QtCyi8V202BvQHq4TJnsUWpUC@mpqdkgL9NuB3kJQiAu4fKqPAvPbZFDCfVqWAKMTiWnTmKOgO9JCUoog0cqJfpP9CAlj4eROsM9xzYND7AY10Di7CpQ0aEDiBEyFugcVssaNYSWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsx8PKvT@OooKkhsgqKSEiE3XknIywbcTiUF6MfM2xAW0JOLVSZVejngstjt6vJYgEZJVs5GSfsKKeH1vn4/ZiRdvoiZFkbHWgK1mtkVyWoPPnraGyjqrROaqC8h9FqiLzYnoCfYN5yRcrVBbRXNNDrbciUAnVcAwxELy6lEQ8qfCbMfTetNUXKgF3QWPn0qgJ6J8LSz0QREmhE/iN9kZL5UCwOXA47Mnu6acV0RZ5YKpp2aU5j77TMvrkvYnRZT/tw8P7x7vH32gsgdG3mqVFj5SVLeSxqx1PlK49TmVVvbQZhjED/KCxHjYmnI8jSyKYKc4kpCpNW9C5THxyHh1/tkgS0ISQHJQDuPG7oNLwOKB0SU3D6y10wqybSECWQRI/LlMOmQ8zcCDqGG74@DwZv36NlbeI1FD4I2b9scEB@J6pQ9tPp2LgggLmBzU7vEektKCFWjaOf85c4Zg@Pp@g1ryIDKnSIZb55Ohg/7hCYHuGd272@wpFSXkj0KUMt60Cz/fHbVNaFgfEH7haLKHOEEd9mnBdSuBWa47As7plK@ADADRxVIcp/YFfNK8HuO8tlo18lVbAAfROEBb1yrA@1PpQREN4YBfXQkt3WS9KAbPOKvBa2mMFofPdViuXM7ezxXC31Zrl2Q4DHZBSbDm@3uhC0LmnoI860yKFWi3QP3l4A3GPlEgwBRQfM6/PVMrL60tovSgWi3qpPbDQnL6pPiOJJzM5nkpF/YFPteWRzRmKvz@xRrF0nD@1OMSF3Hd3D/UHfmQxUEcDGGQ0oAmOPZPbwYmGlgc8Yjt9p@uwLUjDtUM/Q1CbVhZzt@vYN2rIQE8sagRnLkD@4niNMYS@xnpNhiOlCpurfNbDsL1LkNJaPoNEIgoRqBTFV18aFwaQa1buk8Mv96ET0XLpdOBO0wdIEEpD5EJXK@RLHkyBjFSBz9ICBrMYN1q7H6CEphGw0ELQBQl3Z8FLPUliqqml8Zei9DXnBsVfOtMF1gIfzlrgCJHs8PGTh4eP9x/tfnE20nO5ufdsupgHwkF@TdCF1B6nG7bWLd40sVgILgJtw8XmBVJgDAaKPxw@9lwQ3CpGUTkCK7iGz//Evub07KgXXyzMJYYqL@0WZ6FH2Ph4VJEQDO12H40Rl0@bYX@O/NMbjYZeKZWCVt4bN1UwWlMvW07f6KYoHXQM/X5KQ9Pl8AjHNbxlKQAZb2ryFHxMC1SHKQ0cGv2BA8YLTcWhaGAxDp4Gq/pWtwe2MM7XmW5cDTiYSpNqg4UAtnIqKBsJYHoD2oqnX08yZ@2PNL3A@VpL69mU7Eeba/4Qd6NjgukUg94KSBFfeGVnd87usClIaYS0CCTC1C0xZYN9QZ@BIkmDpWjn@8QhaYHDpCgriEavxjiIC1IqlUtnt7V8LgVmGZhpoLMqONSmDIxRq6eMHAXgKU6Hxg1CXNjxWobdUbeEw0cW9L6PoaiZ2vOzM7sOCvrZHcINJ8Jq03pNq8fL7GaSLRE/XgbunSse8q7vAbxLTmBNei5rW3zaNtT@0FhFfrGcqEdj3KgP4OCiN4TMaWy2hdLNw3G1EfQqAcegdAOioHBjl2YUh50Njw/uQSIxWeenBxsngECD2MEArh1MUgLxKBWZtdDioD5wlLE3G51DYxlqCDIknNBoh57XpsH2LrRPSMwLsssLwnMin/kinYM5byO0pskKStMa8bFxZ@ziJJjVDpcNomd0HgegUeFC8pBmy5pmi49O8sRUCjCeDDCtwYAGExy0EmpCJhXB4DNtaEN5OMAL7JhWcMIB4Cvs3h60/pbJx1mUARofTBnus@jITe0qX6YM5TVwwRqdBAu/G574pUo/9QlAI3jBzC@NLoiRQ@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@P3VhdIZOCMj9bkKxoYa6maiG9GUokAPQiEcEhX7keVhEzZs0xl74RG6pQOHmDv4nvbGICz91SZJ4CprKJmtnsOim/cAOgumR1AlwJkehc8X@QDaLRW@KESxN8dJBuiVaRmGBXIRl2jw0QyNkOCixx/TzuWHr9QgtzKlYWnMyOrajmsqQBJIIdGiCVpiI1WZWIlxSCNGN8bzRegeZEkGq2WCRDzoOwbRlovr0DzKcBBKD3YtJDk221If5EcHxKPK68I126ktiSY1HbcHPQSUBiWxHtTWQASkHG/YVkcTSCrFQOubC@RWEShrl6yt63q@leuU/DDkCiB2DyoJrTkbTEM/SNEgMC4qeZ8Pp/i27eOjB/t8zCEFWh@NWuD4U2PgtMegjwl749i0u0m2D/xk2c7AAjL46V@f948dZ8StY3hZNaLBjU1rMO4bNFayOJyxNl3LaTp9GkJZl3QWf@x6Rt/ggzd@6O7nj0BHfnp6UlFLoUgp42KwNm8cv1ueLafnYXiujqYn/WkVjzOmvJmTsd/yF3GhmBEBeQwYiyVcUEe@/zb6@00K5x6EfwH9B7h8C3RMYX3Ta@ApIhYpIi7pwpUwwvNKS1@j/0rbJYinUTyucM2wvdJ08r8YdTpz3hnyPldQNPVn3lny5ku75myrMEo5HgnXec3FCQPKU5xguddiPCG8gqn5ntn3Z96OQTHB2SXo2/uoPoFOjxosX3NlggI6xEkEktA4NcVaPcP1bpj70KaGCo8tRTaonUAflkLNRdpMMTE0XKaWAuY2n9LzuPR0wCSmUYedKp/oRZPD5dZOig9abzYAxE617K/CWRUNc4pGg2gElXCDFFRMmu6@UdRg8YJHY9ESJSlLXgq07YmeVs4m2/v1lEdE6DD57GzycVr/ApR2XCu1eSfVNcuY3Upq0Tsfv231QGywxGSeZFAPY7vj9NsKnyyC@mfczMCKEFP0wWotEvjgY7n@Qi0LF3@IBXUgLkNrvG7AXai66s0IoVVhASBoDVfszXny4g2rQQ92oXrDvjWqs2t15DR6WPjR2LUX149xldJ1jakniRUeFbZ7/MnntXSdQ5AGBk4AFXhtTfzlh6AHg96DqzzBhetURtaIOnaakLewvJoKSE1orgDQBxg8gzILMhIlQtTfmG9mZemYYLDFTMTcmw6SzIxfq52@MRqZNuctPgu3mtx8ukRkU6Hs74qx9xJL0wQFKJoWhgGKZXZy@mD/@FgFDvVi0X2cyChBszNaPdA3VhXap2S48CX2cTvKPsY0cbReJWhSYEw0RHpg3jIwN5gTkDuKgq7pxsAzjnMQLfCmaR9KyBUuQSBcbdQaEY0CYDGwpu9yYKWl@D@1ueUk8CyxKEsQJYHcsTsloK0VV8e29Ur1oN8gNRSiRLntSUtLK5sxEl@bWpz4x7UGOIcKJhNpgVCGWo1tgHSj2DKrvGXPa2mlWE9ssnq9zGfGISHq9LRUVSx7NAQ9@TQSCUiB86GwyjoLi1/9HGjEE1Nx/DTgWUnwLSDrjpvTm61U3tTleICs8ho8eKC8iOSSxZkcRX9JEIkQWkE0vxJofp1RqFhPycheWFQNxfERCMqD03cxXkq2UWFaPO5jxgE9M1w0nUvsieN5VrNPqz47fYuvoAo665IgjIDkUyacXRkbBtEN2zO0M6yM2VJfvoBWUILCqaMBSwpLRh6xOLtCYhIpdaQie/MGPWS2qTNiAxlX2nL6Xvs2LcjHhw4g@1CsHA7rHCQ0xLIOFB1nkuwbb/PzphjCDYPUxYLOq1zI4XRc57Tsc4dmXwJXI61qOdQzg9SD8/7NlB3L69HPXNQABx5XX4WdN2h26GdJBJqEENPb5EHD20LDhuo0Usf0oJHuJTnPL@mYy7ZpdsZ2l@YC0c2UV7fEVIoFitxpNq1VUYEIuErLfy6JBrISW56uZlXNbz04wAPdIshPbhPNir64GojN0R06qRGkEs//@s020P9m7fSgv8JxwMDRAE0Ba0rprKwskRRf6Gd5xfLh6nHfMogw5LoNZMtwoUhGP3AsB01T4ooC@sYAB/hFjQNv4g/oomvYjGPO5@f85/JMlk1x2SC3W6viLqyO4lnRZAyYi20iAte5LJMSkZDllWBO@IRIyHBHgXs7Uv4SJkbMzOu9Nx6N@S@ow7dWojXE77q2KWKmc0ZTM8EgNZqWuabKXeN83HaU4Xk3UIvzS@LOSk8zsgpoJWJytoHO5cXnBXStLnT3/nNVtFn/mrqkx21c4dljb6g0ybZv8zdqCIM1Obh9/rsqiiV2@ASO1VSz@vTznpwooAOjiLUJKVz5qYSIZi2QuW80p6gK9T6cy4J5fpA4lVYikc6smOgdDlenR/uU0heLy1NP1Banx7KRhxRfXarwsTkqsFhvekutQndlDYy@ordDzpXCfNkygRtRgxlGSmNe4PzKxdKam1EfO6TWuG@4M9caFp/h4U9OrBrnFt2GaMstp2952KD7q6Smv1Ztlheu76Wf0HoEaxkl22CIYj@uBK7lUsBpjXAN5wq2eg@ZxtdO4grVEJ@ozipitZxL/K7UIHpgDPPf5Z3a66VYvYd8UvqtvgFd@coeYW7UEUc1b@HVS8sz6Wc5Yc@XIjpq9Zf6z7cCfzwxPD54G2d7Vt/x2An9riNQ1wUq8N/lPB2mpWXYCo2yh91rxJC/6GBWoUa/6/TzhW7KgJ@VtT52Oyj6xfN9hVwgpDTtFiHla0COrYnnStF@nnLPb6sg2jfl4oLTkHNNL7tMUolJndWlA9sAZwSXl@wgXaCUaoqPIa7IGOdyLo2p//wFeo9VpPV7j@GUNGpQ8DBBsQCOkcu17F8kt@z63NrvJ5RugN2@rRChyj3vm9Bf0e@NKmV6WvvAFFo6/f4iqtMfm2Nzqa1x1Hxp4vbbNXbG@yOVFsXYFFMAOOuAe0WCWK@FcfheWGNXjW9rhYkBVrt5uzYzL9SGoIAP0Xp@Ao4n6LiZomuPh3O1Omeg2cfrSdYb@k3aac9hhyEfKocKtyhLcyq6Z9J3rdHEjTxcsVXJptNpocOEpnLmXtYZU5kg7UuL/85lTD6znGdxcfrODTmX50FkCa8JXCmC9FW2PUUuFlO2ZZujKf6@pzRtOk7/Q2oKhGrbQm0MlEta@7quxm6oO2JXB5uNXng45tHsrBq34L2NMC@BPmg3r6v08FzTe9WmgrOpA5zpmn9dP4ITmrm6LRfcBo3DQnw1bH@1LikGRDS1oG6vbXVcQ3WaZt/gj0k@uw5eUc2shTcvNMQsMM4a87ni2Rx/ZEEoDadALKsNhkrPHJj0ukbRN9ovx57/WBlp4uB3VfDENFupyb7ZWhVhaIFcsPF3bnI6pCyNHBtMrBEuvENTpY9LO4XvKgnsTycuJfLhwOia/GyHdZJyNmaBy3S4ZTdzLh@9KPGlOS1INhthXs0S0KjOzannP5cCfDRtQb2OB7ePuC00/hYOg75Ha1@1pvRmF2v3nJ7dM3t8IXfwtqpxAD@O@Fkc61AHrLu9FiPRFF5zHqZn3@n334eeKBq5oHSczlKc9nE3Km6l@iC4U6MJAeJx6/idMeKyAx0rW03PHEO/5DkjZ2gq9LYqah/HevjvKhnqz37/ooNIa019oIj//EXh32pbdg1nNBzSozHsjz36oaQKbSK@TW/q8DUvSHbmuF31tTNoqsJTFQtiaNJ9uYhpWqNWDzdvc842u06z1bNuQ7ppGiPbOk/5oz789b1sV6SMxZQH6K32LSCvO1WRXyrh8BN8HK6qdDGAxLu1wLFGX1k2SEf7pJWhcd7y@IAoulgJx4RDrZHvpi7RNvTSq7E1mgENLZIKRnj5zAQ6VuEulmWs1Kxo08JMDIvlGiu5lJR0VMgVMw0Kj7ZyfGluAV2oiWUy/GcVQuFSEkahBS8fQm6xqIgGCK3Q0C34z/HX3GqopZ2c3Rt3vZsCk4/Yt0FFw5@lInC3i0cw4bZYh3l955KWqtHJA7O9taHxbOjNDFs8VlWA3k/hfkR4NkAbG5trJ1xya2dcKJ7WVwzHgkcDHlCp45Wja31r6PFfpnRWztOJ5VNgpS9OJnKqTZeb2aLK2maHz4@g6zblceDQDC5oJ0oLZ/txeB3FPFfJuEiznS6Ie6XPZpH9uKsUmqUrk5YzRtCbKl88NrsGLu9@aI1wfegSfiFmXrai6VbYXx8bnvX1MZRsFRvi4Qp8jtIN78LHtyXwHhldq/XpXEUESAoCi8Wl/DHXMNDrZl1c9iwPV1cFjjVDVshynImR6xpgUSyJuTioH5wrMWv1fMfi0tjLBt6d4RQ3dk3JtW7M3RrR@Kt4rjIqV607W4vE5XgwHHvisRwHWr8VHp8enJO/d2kBcOUVCF3WM/qj5WPYocFY0M9EdzlzrtLTv7T6Tpd9WUgzUOdAPUO1fQnj3IeO@wkuGnLtJZxIeb/nnCgOgShc9nmvoG7NDFMs2xqtH@cZjXABkf/EwvA@BTdFpB7ir3rvQyEop8sp8vB2K2C2i/iWnh8478QZuy0TncHRIGGDQeRq7vkLnkWvYZuXYftt7bwOdJSOPR4p7the2yvk1/YKJTYp5ENswGJf33/0NB7mBlogfpt@aoJZOPb605lr5WqCBSazbFDRVsvR@di@lfGAn2R0TKuTb0mzi8cttUhcP3CWWUJPpq45em9TCoT/ePDAbOGc4q15P3YeObYDvdEQBOXg2OTb8@dWgSxPiMke4gZ0oE/71mxOCOyKTohrG8bQbEL99meu9@mLOOAHxshY0RXRqCFZhoHrVl6x@k3TfUnDgSH3KmN3HqFPzQlZHasZhrdBZdRqcWUZR@rm2sjcXI43dByb/5K0TcNDe7ReqkBXQD/vP4uu4tr/uRGDpZbbfFGPLvgSErPNz49YVVbXbDp9/rtmwZJt8QUDhmuZXuohHkdAfvksU0D78tbKkO21MmRmNIEme2F4NIO/3AiZgdQmH7A@qGe4LQfnyIRjzdKd0BkCt4jpYDsBX1XQBMJPQGIZrbE4zfA2tPqD5oB@VpoSodo8Npu4EalJB2@MjMnNyuRjRuLUgdByr2Cvvi@usFHnWewJ2Cnx27utOQtrnqrWkH5IUq@cSKeVPIptma3XBo6nOUSv2aj1XDiUOfWYnCtGsUPNiMaXUwZtSl/akubXtYFC0zeVUc81QfkdrRv49k9EWTJTMh6YOP08Pz@zUnV1vB4V1lk@0x4IV9dUxGl8IEuCk/m4fqjsrtQ8ETz8H93/Wgo64UY@658SAqLr9rl9QH7s2uLxPhz4xPFGHWtyBHjjjoRV4gSLlYMk8OAtA11bqwoBtWeP@3xcohtalDVokzmm0ImwitIncT0yFdO@UOjMtsnNEjl8n1lqF48XHZltRRxZgHMQykN/y1kQTTyXTK2GZSOuBNVSnLCTfFasDV1G3EtfMoC@5YyUoUfP1NB7cvjw6FQdetpyq7@HOzVu6HFzZyDohXRosOql4YZmQvlatbbljVL3TzRl7@GhihFW0JvPdSjwwDm7ucfKEVFxmKeRMlZaQRhqjpYriJ@ePnqYmO0KZbG9nusMzHg4eO/kJIm7Xr52sjQ4nPoAWkfHmaxMfrivafEl7PvUpnnDVdJzSU6rIJ2aYI0CM37Kj1C5VblqOUOzfTodmp9D54kS3HvP7PMrC/nYuLC62ApZcSWhqKGyoprPxkPLtsHYNt3guao@z60hSssWPVL8sXKhCmoOmZSbWa49rFsLsKjFsLRYo/BhibT0TW4dWQq0jG4PXSnD@/sipmnaKjqfGB2oV5ZbWVnzEZbNHPedi/eYZDaF8aIEXsoIuEqxbl1kvq0MQHSn8AcH7oUnOJsrF8isAxB455c2@EvTnhq2QrNc69SLEqTG5W5ro3xpvsdUVbD25wKPWF46@xest2exFjnjt2R86oaS7O3dP7wtwbGg5fpYnzx@yp4YHp4Xsj5iGGPzPTCeaUYvFRy3wsPqVk60tl0Apa@F1x0ub88ldmK4bceeTm6fnqNtr9i10/G/ASx8o0hm35pYy/qqFh/XerJ8AdJtefMdHs50Tg8OnyODvnxXzPHYDp9v6iXFTnu@mY1vL/JU/xDaWMxIJOLx@XPOw5up@DYiA0@6px1AEPfNG7YhNvpAQLD3SWwvwsNyQLcwcVOe5IOosc0rsRmnVNKucUOSXJKZ2CwVHBzID7@rbMbw2C5AlSnnGt70wDb9nTyMTm9mbxjpGCDUtFwa3tRUeGtlWWxxYiXI9snhk/2T093Tpye1dP1ajouNfBw1w4DM/C2eH2faMpRIEAO6fn4SJm0F7EN2dLI06iaeXywGBVsoWWWuZLMyyXcxzeaVYaRStKMtpVwDforMc6NQEEToxWH7JSaqiw2JJb4RrE8UlTc5aJnyhJoosfSyjIeG50GxRPji2fYUyjIZDOUZi8MLgR27jtMWOXomu/3j53iwe/jw6fE@8xGcscKl1R71KsUcP9sS27diQj11LJocr7CoSBKFuqpUogdRIExUjbIS7SOkcyWBeyGaTx3cgShSb7HYJsEHCkaDSkn912@mrqMqrvOKQ9yoj1SUCcpjBHaKe4P@7Hfb/Nxl/0QA/wIHd0B6Ne28lsS@vxW7/pCi1NyGq69xoHOOaYNfcMDy7GoMiY7dBq68RHVr8aCXOJ29wO/kEOfw@BkRg/hnteKwAJ6pAzbNhYW7@zgOHTziZp6VcY6RjkNS2S7eUQE8D6yPSADqY3vEj5EQm84jwEdqICaSbJOQ5SeFy6GI0Z0NYOWm2bVs5tmga5mjEnsJfIamd4lvMVWUavRGEh80v5xE6Y0G/VDEG2fieKmzUerdr3031S0zcE/S9@HtV8RbB9y/yt3PU1jXN8/NmeUfRgLPiBJY88wDmiO9Q9dx2Hwr74xYeLyPL/@YNYCquSBKY3SeA/9VbCbP4MRqn0NFAYtBLYktvDw/063H8JCqUiqFbITTGCotWzQnfA3BwmFV@Vw@q6UASeXCB0iny3ZxfxQHGI@XgPGlC2tYedEE9trZYTJ23WYlX@a1mdo0nmfkFwGimxBXuuwhcjUGaSDJLAWEVUUy6CQSWhyTojyKalEURW0Heg8Kx14G321BCJnFgFicRiYeVzrBe1lG7tQ/dK2Jd52ETh7fFIAUDbogcsVlSew6feyMgGXm9tvyXae4hob3VDjj7PF7h@isM@RB9WZrmm2W8o84F@1LxXbPQWXSi51euG7lZwjiBEGU5GUsW3vOzkZndj3FeZMBm/5IsGyYmW1w/7NUdwXP8nLv3jyxK7Z43hYSi907sR3UUQ6gMCymp/RMSsvHZ0XKZpcWSZRIZAPFwXME3kB2IJpATLRM66Uz9Hb39g@/dvTk5MapVBQzuhgNJHl1J3GmqMlaPXBEw8War5L7B6mTR/cP/IqYIZ0PSWDQSURJtHUlmZkeCHK2yHWxaMswXCzdaoyf8Z1wi/hm9HWoUaIbeGjpD8iXFpopB7RcfDFzvbCMWrncOpRm8FIh0Ht8r88NVGPxq@tafad6ZkeiNzlhSUN4HlG3sBGA68zb2kwhs98sHBYsuB/sFG828cJtMbO8LcqbGTwcBXcbjpzz2bEwwiMUECqvnw2ISElN@VFXtr4jrkvPDi/S@f1l/BiV8OERIYTz6XUUD4E69a9CQykyO3pNnDrWAwOgbzUl/9AOfvqYf0hScPAYP3AjFpfEwdc845i4HG1Smqg0dxyLo7QjWEm27iAzH15cggaN@tqTMRgiT5whPwiV5ggemL7r2AHx@2DMJxtN9rXxAOJ16HFs0ngNSG4FEgMlowGqXH8CKSHOMZsk8KQ4yK@Gp5mJgquDdi42ias9c9K2uiDbY/EkSLSPNa3OgrPOsNB0tpkdlanOZrWwtil@gju4wmT/oAPvJjMEjJqhWnbbnMSil9F4qQ75o3/08tlFNC4v4yU6eE@cRNdePIEvQH9bWy9JjJFonf7xdsukRbF4U0qA3yJgfnSMfwtDsaj2PIku06mgLn4ych@CE9SIWGdgDFlsbPPjdVRGr7GzmJ2k80iUKj@hy2aJBJlI8KAAlVHKDrl4/x0z7CmLpSrABOjr2W18vLaGrKapah3clEmcbeLtKHugceFRFXEJbFVIUiKwFWQhMBwAI95IVM7gkAbDJTxBxKVDipYE02URNOLpIE2o1Kx6h4UuuZnXHOVisSQqdF4qFhlw301xqKYA7A055@vyQF2xFR5oBgatKkVmgvymxItQvhGOyKdiDz2gEwmdqudvrWcAa3bmXavn4je2b0NbwdNASk9PDxqFeEpmwV78rmu1cdiFH6gaGG3iCHxopqm5qNEyt9E@wWR4yFKDb/bHM4AOqMHICyI1EibD4pWPM97UtLVcLxKKWoCYWewAxIaFhg8OTxPzJ8CWhC0X9j//OV4qKcc27@Yzjf5FIppLl@FHK@dYjn28eaYomzU9l67c26wbxuhMZkYqu/Xgwux1mofd1JksswzLplJbev7V@VDLbz2vqa8mdblWqCTP60/O2ZMnX7xtvI3Lk4upfBZj2xG2d/RG1qAAkdI2KzL8Lv3QbW9LP2usdDkKcM/O8LJIeVtOpWrROvxT0Av48Ei1qlpV79bfvo3XtqFMk@lZBO9gY0f35oHFdD1@YllWip0NvXYbvk6P1fktohH@SSRiChMeSo37scGkQ36TXbPbHe8bU@5vRcb4OBiJtI@@fPbsGTqe0Ye9PhbpOXTm51FqGLkI09P6n/104zp59aSx82ffGqTMDXwc4eO714/QfaLlPt7Y@Pj@/Ww2CVTi7idfPvnG7u5u9kEy96SWu5tV0hs7f/onGxu6vqOnNuqep9WjtfPzL2Q9nZXVP/tJtPHkydc9D6sFPxmmgRN/C/DVUKc6Z6/hc95h@E/u1@2Q20B3s/Oa6ZHXEWDryJT@GhHGW2GFtKTwZ4Np1bvb/@37R68io0hVTz1z4TmKvIrkCxHuBAe8Zfy3i0g1soPR8teRaapSqYBz@7/9e0hf/RrAwZDpDvxUcz6s/DRSVSqU5E2kmgeHpuuQ7//9zW/eNu5zrwYfObuty3fr8Nmiz46EJyAp6VRqIbZWuKPdYcwe9Uamgw@LP2x4MKNsg9V9XEskEnVVgY/aoEQpTdPPaMAmzFo03hIJvMuM@7CQ34xPhA@EPYsQTwFTEV9xt/AgVuMezxbjPVvyKT/7x/kcS5H8xj3zQbUKAlCv6lvVBH02zkolKEnjXiPFtguy49zDcazomRxlL9hDQeKqnC7ocjKZvNfAi3nZBCmpTCIzsjFOGRaZo2eEzd5Y2CvC/GRsFudD4@3j58//9z//wZ9/n/5@QN//hEdE2W2rk9riyF9U@YdVq3LVla/O6OUeS5cKpUKqwa7PYlu1av2YaelP3kRzmegJlpEisbO4P64ZCT7VKv74aOBbNcJ9qtw18xMh1eCFYsySLI/HhDzyiRqBjlesl1FqF3WOG@E38T@z1lC7B9Uk69tFuV7Vc/oRVJ0mU8UVWW/TY07EL9Fd@GzAH/3D5y6OGQsf/N0gTx5CUZd8NgJcbv/MNVopUqul6mYd9FdW9YHc2yhtFEr5kg61shpweRXoyEVYhqjbakHVQWq8rW2wY87sdZbwP2eJWz9PVbUhnORw8KsoziQiRf4RPlWJRa7gU3@7VXu7xRp@3jXRUhM7Sr2aECjBQ23cqyeU6@ua@jxRLov/nWrgLNOHu6Ak9WtF2XkOsGo3oXKg9Ks2nu8A2MRObafi7NFXbSCNlfrzam1nPq1Ifu9eAmXrPQBQ3ayzaNaJ5p178URiU1E2aiuLAHDrMQbGAFTg9c519bq2c329swP/O/R7LZ7ge71z458es8@KOLNwajdntVT1LHUm2KYO72qqij5q6gwcVXhCPOh9pIgCYk6KbLGtyJBp2xlwMbOkbemZVG7ycX4fNKJaXUHDpaLUtHyurnBR9UJlJYUfLK0V8nEVZVHD6TRwL5jKXkiRF@@@@l/xe/buq9/H7h7aZVGKpLbQKihy4wB@Htns0aNH@H1k2/AP30f8Y6MPejxCP5v/2DyGHyfw5j7UHkgsFPJyI6FNdRbZkfPbKBd@6cYnGo3@kxd6cTvKDWfcM/XCA89fWvb5J7@06iNF3hSxnbc8xsskRajdQ11A@6mi8wp/mq/w7@Fr/Hs1wr/TFv4dv8I/dvoa/45H@PeoiX9PPPw7fYV/u038Ox3g3/1X@PdohH9Pu/gnRSqgY2/eTffTrbR2rp2Dw2Jpl6V76Z7WRgMgbbL0ND1l6YGjtcFlwl8aXFa6w9JdlrbTtqZBIDhGLD1CVwceXfjrABQX/qx0GoGnWwxy6QNQfqcKPd@AIIufSTWwHOUXJmjDqqam1bxVxxO1a3JdLxaYihRWG7UXZ9E6HtWoF7OsOTU3zl6wiAeadDmSOjtL8TEBpmfLePj29XWjsf/4QaORQlF09sg5mv0fHQ3Cr2v/B0fOoyNn4MD/0dHRI2ZWE/cSyj34VKqJHfG4G6mW756VFGy3vqSIpHbunlUzCrrzCWj8OvolPvAzgwjP6saZFGWgqlyWSQ0qX16UL8vkCF7B0SgHEUQ07gDPslCfwKfs61GX8Lm4JE/8Qefls7PAxR2pZ5dnaA6AnRf8g54Zfv0H@Lf@v/X/6CmL1eqg4MSurndi9InjXzx@dX11LX6r8VhMvMR24A894B2TXF1X0UmRrsBVi8Xr8etr7ge/sfgOB1jFPHaqlHgWERp/JMiT8uU/sX/YJ@YtPmd4qHNogv7sbJJOx8tN/xBZnJwy3tA8abxMV4JsNmta/U9/QkcF341TpFy2XNa2GH/Rs3q5nPXftgvlcsF/2YzFijc/1fRdLQ8KTjYbj5fL8HLXB5uG1wBsAcD6LzmAanpGi9p9OXJ1eESH6IKYyEXiWCIuGGJpOmsbr22IyiX5zp2YuEbx7m78zh29mH7zJvAZDsFLm/NqNNqW22igf@bNG7kh04R5MQfv6cKbNyDLonHHjT3G2z4go5iisY/1KuVZdFwgxDYEMy2lz7DoGZ4xGrmx19YwKePqVE@O02H86bTjnkV/9r1vfessWqnIiky@WQ0BYC4st7OTz1ar@Sy48wWglLx5xe@l6CaKWvx6MyVzajB5MxoRQVphO85lYxTDoYdjd6vQwD38sKvrCFU7y@biMZCucVC0riP4x721YpH7s2w@VkgUxV9lI86qoAPwPzRLM4ns1vbWvTqjv8myD4rk8pVZ0a4rV2YJR/euyy1xRRluCzPv3MkUgaaFdPlMajQe7J7uNhoVWZaxO4Qf9CThLuENL0M3WqMKzxXrNSxf/SwaLZXvEXNohRyLRMsinhKFXoIVikQGyergnk8ou6QJm39D0umJP5IYAtoAT7xFHG@L4Y8nD3f39k@T@g5oNPrB7l5SP3l6P6Lha272TsEZfD/e331w9BQSPHm4v3uy/8nh5/tPn4C/xy5nH18Ai9/ZM@xa8n7Jnkkv3deGaRrm2DQbl@Px5Sv20rIaFtC1P7Ysy@m6zDMbpmkOIZr/KcO3ZXnGy5eGO6QPe/ej77z70X/37sffe/fj77z78Q9@9tUPvgPf34Xv9/jze/@umMPfn331P//Ou9/@MXj@J/j@EXx/@rOvfuOb/Evvfwzf/xLy@2PxDcXjXwlg/crPvvr@T3721a/@EL7/Snx/ePP7az9d/v3Bt1d/Md33f2d9nO/9e/j@Hoflx/3eb3M/fN6I/9s83q/@8N2v/wf@/6fiD50/fvfrf4w/4uWf//BP/8u7b/1HXS/86b99953vvfv29999@1vvvv3dd9/@p/q73/i3Wjr88zvvfvAHf/WHv/dXf/g/0f/v0u/vvc//ux/@87/43/7i//iLPxTfn8L3P4Drp3/xH4Fn//YPfoT/3/@Dv/2jH@H///Kv//YP/uXf/sq/Icdvcsf/86/@Hf/961/7z3/zW9/9q59@82/@5U//5jf/4K/@z1/9v37jP//1f//7f/0/fgs9f/Onf/VHv/KX3/rOX377X/zlt75a8fudtb9fvYf/V/8IPu@P5/vAeZ9yfajPV78QPn8fasxyAT4BBv9n737jl4HHf52//Q/wBv9B0HeDl7kQ/vLd2QtA@K2FRBGzNN9TFPRCYgvU6a1iUfQWQfAOpfzZV//iJ0EWvzwPdS4Mcvwutsu5sO9ii373o2@@@8k/ffej33z3o19B2a1ki8ndpKKtH18Fea/k3iMeRsy/TzyI@MUXkP8kQQODSgLf2Bci8IsvvpAmb1JgEaXvvQHfL8iLfxgPgjAmgvww4Y@rMcNxuDPtOzfR@004ayRDArNNUL@35XfKuQybJARGE8ZHzNAfIk22yDnBX/LF4ImEP7P/mXMisQTGEUNviZmTHCKdyII7pRxkk5iN05GWwHjPzIcpJzRTQvlmiwxLMJkkJmB@gQNySEDQ/QSrVCoJTFjh@MArR61aYIRKIlGBcmNqnibZKCCIyX2CAikriWPW2KpMeMIEwqv65EhI6HUsa7qcKFQeQIaVyQOGsBA4gX3xolItVCZVBPeW0yMxSdwnnBBYJTGpvoX3CsFM4AjKg7eASqGSSFQLmCEWkldPssErKUeFo7InWELUATxpOPIeYx/LWkHmo/YbSDAeG38Ts9h3aR7pLoSfJbZEcejfd9J3iwi@QVmJXBgPv0t60V2uKmEEgKsoqqoy@CoKYnMPgiccVIKyhUeCQ0gQRxAHBB7AhlgXCarfBL1A/pHK1gd/ElWJl2Zzc1OKVOWMfESzGAkwUd3zEr9I4Q23A0pMzhdl9DZpdTMvnbn5hGzsrQdb8KvB//4GLTpOsDKhtRnFkawo4/mxjxP8e@/eFvsYSk/PmZ/ElETGyeJQMhZ0J5GQdci16iSk5yDdJGBfAvRGUicVmjtJSMkkY2olgmHs6OhIoEYezytSArhfz2j4jsPe4/E4AilUNakmk@Kp0pM8VOFQKVQ81U2kOY28MV3PlkGZLzP0YmHdWwMjDT3fvn0LlUULD0qHYD4xsQZBzxYoEDz4jrp@f@qveNezRYnbjkzL8yuCY3QTWpzFJRZjW3GJL1HlSARTmlG9UIiiKw51osa2/CUpeU3yB8RoPCx01z0aNIVc3A/cO2J7R48e7T8@HdbrTDLpijqzIS58XyeYY5hu9/EDvoJdL@YRjUithjmflnQUS9J@KU1C8/DB8eFJiXGaiBqKBZDiZRrsFKQoalJkOHy2ExHT9jLemeDIJ/hbmpU/phczmGG1LEVaJirhwHD4z8rSI69735mA4ZqU5aSWR3skTsOFTPqGUypV3mrZbQme9D5meIYP3/AHrRPXOas7O0Q0qXql0BAvOqGC81K1Kta/ME2qnuyfQoLTI6bpaZWBWXuV3dazuWxOz@TzuW1dy@aL2XyukIG@Jp/O6bpWzGaLheL2tVT9gk1UxFUBd7/SN@3uqLeJq07ks7QcosdmLZ3EPz2TgV@AmNRy2/WNjf6VggieEVtc4fKha3i9UpACH8GHSR9J7CPwgg/kgWuCmFiQdXhUFqticGt9jC@NkbUcNO64dAaMxMFJw/CnPPc2hLYEZm7oK0U2vvxyxKpVMC@VwwMpAiKrx/xlIorVVnsqMVV77JoU2mWsbX1u4bUaatvyhn1jCg01rUqR6@vrDkA6PMDZRHrlKdr4e90inya4ryeG9P9//kE/O/zwmSqu/HeMdgU3MtGRF9Dg4lftSttp0WU75U6lVqe7k8pttem0p6o3moIgFBVZiTb7Tus86gdaeJsh7s2rpIyU2kDxMnIajUolmkpF7@rbudJGyk2pdNYWi3Wgud7V89vgeWZz31gHfHLo83zeq1hqqz5Sj4BtIZ1e0vO56x1xAl0VyoSoVRGRK4FfyXZs8xrX7JeMDsjiqxZfmFWS9VxBLtfKs/ftvFyuX98bmG3LYGdpXKd9tTRhPi9f@/EgaxMaHG0Dig3wxhfc7VFKn6XjKxKnITGgTJhKO@LQmyotNKqB2KjjhfK1@o5/HA7025KuK3pGyWiKlsH/Wxw6/r9/fB3@dfyFVBldOsUtYY@hukE82uwhnss7ctip49AVTPfN1ooYez2DVlTtuY7n/T3i3Dfscx70wOLnsARBnxp49ro3sEa9FTGeDge4Vc10/9Eg7A@agCDyII9wH37cvuMsi7DNnj5ZUcpHwclnQAx@9BlEPz785NPT0PN0f3fvUynP7h89frDwyIlIOfZw/@A0eN3moX7SXADiG/sPHy6@ikcEO1Ic/dtguW3foUm4JPMOmBF3hDOXnznT6HzGdwtZXrBEkG8LK0mn/hYiah9W02QtvnsQ7RrafC/UG227KElDZjuXbDvN2k6/b@D1c50N8OwZuDXCxA67T7ckYtaXjttvQxMzN6RHuAujqOEdW4iE9CkAGYxbtNPVGkl4lEsbL4bD0eYm3m09xssXV3jCA73Q6eKd8mx06fgRpKZhMPh@6AfSm@HPaL3HiOdBfjdC@jejSxHJGBmRQhkYtty2x3fuaE9cYO5qIV0qnaWvgbsq981y87w0ND1z6FX3J8BrbMyeAvcbLgrJ3mYKLV62mZPzLVkvHbBskqmNiLGFdO9alRo7AUWlPjxmBRwhbRmZ7Bbordjbg66GU7F//Vu/i7y7lQIxFdFkGReFbmiSSgqeXizkCsWMXkgWioVsTsvncklNT4L@vF0EFSetFbR8IVfUkoVsMZMFjQlCc8VtKcLX3qS2CCQ8SwDWbuF1UDukI6q9qhTh0w7sdcyIs4gRvI@ZbEIaGS8Ahk4Gd51tWRVZzzItzcA8AIgGa7HIwcFe@uBAlu/jC0627qVluY0vuUI6vX1flk0K2QOtTpdlh6cp4N55ecRf0un7e7I85gDw2DlZ7uHLfh5HF2TZwpe93YMDzKeDLzqmh2jnPIS/9P2XbYhm40smQ8MTsvwqAAfxdnlGWcJ0H18wTww54CF7ECbLn/j4pNMA4ZjH4xA@9cu6uyvLh/xldxdD9qjgOY7qZ/iySx9ZhmrHdiHLXXB0sbeT5SY4sXXIcgtcrakBfnj5Fp5NZo8MWZ5yAiGJZHlCsY3WuQwmuPDHbD799FOjN2qbXf6ZuvzZAtQgxJqM9w@an3zS7Hab7nR3/5NjDNnb@9ToTMdus9sUyZoN@DiQBkLOB9PFD@B42GgY/aUhn0GIvRDSmDZMxK1hvAKcxKeLmQwaexCyByHLZmw4NPgMIGoTP/cH8LxvNCnE/1AIPSfNplxGRsXjBegGTWgzdJllcmC0XKeM75PKBmPRWDQ5reXT9TIFsAFoaOnyNV2dGaMby9GcjV9Na5NKul6ZVLZ1PtXficlnEz1nycmNwV2tCMqXcVfTs4lJCfeeOp0oiyraXRbT7my9ZrHHoGZlsiX57O5dRa5p9bu6Vijlt59vjWU5XsLfu5ntEkRMR8HYw594bbt@F3S6WZLt7YSR0kvb2/HyNZBjBL1nE83MRix2aRrn8Tiii0YJFIFf3DmlclrlTmySnFQ4XmwaL08qWpkfm8PSN2C18Yy2cWvkuBxiF8BN7qZLdDWorBULMuSfSsXicZBMJETgOVvI8@zrp@enp1@AzAJzTxhLT/h9c2Xx@smneyrYT@INz1ZTD1BFdlx1DwXLXAg/@sv3OjUnI/VT6AJBXfX9cD@A6/TV/QmYsKhn@wH@iTmqOOdEPf10Dg4KYJ4zbqcs0058u2UyPHrOajOjUgWX0QYjncSdEb@kzrdRrVYalQG/3bMapPqMX48@A3PocdyDTZ6U/ArXyIuARiV9PYv/eDxg93kkuq3YT9ao3IfePF228chVE1832SQykaptPJXufuX@1biEgyTXZbNi4i2ocgS3YN@1K2PbMzrmE9PFPc2HR5vQy@DKerANTBbfZGd0Z@oeKuPXStVl9hwuMUOpNnFcYc4z9IrkA8386z5hrmi/B86UXoNlE3seL7@CN3eTxdrqfTBGsuV27D5rxMEr/aLzosN0ls@W6SqpGMEykkRBuo80Xql@BjoOB3xeKgEyghPOASjmBHCtNgUY8aF1Xe5Wahj5Df7sKLJcV5Tam7pUVZRnUhUab3kaMSreuElnl7J0U9PT@fIE/LTtbLnHmpXm80nZrQzBtGblPtS@GE/g21iMMtAQKAVwXr9hsXe//M34jpKrcM8yAXvTBz2ioTYqk1lVZSo1PZtP6vksDj/kM/DVknpGx9XoST1dTOoa9NbQi0N6@G7Dexa@EAc6c13DQYpYPyYzJifTk7SqJTVTSwLR0y@s9ot48jwGCgkRLZ4cOft4Dyt4ICMB89IrPI14Qt/qx9oOM3YUYmWQJmUqp5HssaEFPwjn2DT6PH5cYZmtWH8zhpE2T8fD/Vq9VNqfDL8OQTHl1d18YjudeB2Pl2MgQuMVz3wlVctSFYUPUWG4Aawtxl6YNx7U0htQ7iuloVxDdY82tW29VBtv1hQNCph@092Rq3KdQY1dM6HsoFDh@s5MY5n5NVCrxhuNmVbUy5JKE@qUnRbTi6t2Q8QlXMolAEpDIRCRuix2JvvbumLR6LYejcajZRyi3ZDFyBpIQX45Mojj6B3trgw6llySizpGmAlT2rmTDqtZ1xLayyxblCJX0vXV9Q6YnSlaWQXqINsgl6JW70mREmOg652JsyFSG4x96IKtxE71OX@e4ZJOgCvR4UY1VqdlFKaFthL7HHcp3mVRQMxwBzVdz9Rr@jb0gSBX/ai6rpVxADqCS0fVKlDeuwL8dhJVXOD/GZtOjYTiU/YOY93EpkSFjiySfbey2z3eLftvezjsdSbJslyOypGraCR6DX9ShO8q0PmuAhYJ7SvgSxJbJtDnbYTkBdu78gdVSnj4fswocelQq8ffPrb6V4WMwu1@EFjX15HNFNWIWKZd/uyFnoM6sh1/3TbYPyPoEaB7y@VwAC@SejH0vtQLmUeHR/YD98D012dmG3I1wtKagougyyXhm@OrNuViQZf182SE3YuUI@xciWolWtrNhifF59vPC88fPT16enQgRc423mw4OLjLfLKwt/bXvg4Ro5lslLGzSmRSyZbFyplqVdF2dHYXegGGN1x3tLySflPl7FulgLwOIe9@@YfZyU4B3nXQcEtQhbmEXq1qWzqLR4bvvvp93G5/tf/57kMW9Ywp@7s/@Ym@/Xd/8q9pPUr0uuzR4OF2BGKiU8tvR66uhldX1/DhYblIPcKRym7Hwc1HrbXIbPF4KWUYW9uJrH7PLqdEXG1bi0c8JSLG5rdzEe@NCNLTBQjyB8/JS85jFUT2j62crt3bQabQgq0mbDZHa3pF4IrCoxdvGIOXVrXd7Vo6uVIpVnqrsJ23yg57i4PPb5UN9qJSxQlTDTeo@COsW9VqFaGwaDWR2ooyPQdhtetyPcFohBaMwefmlr11Ns/RZxusWLTB3/S2xPD@2ZYHlt2WTX/mlufBq/9mbr30mIwTEKlUu03nkOyYLFeF@t9KATpn8Xe//Bu6nv@7P/m1N403jS@gbygWi3lNj/xc@/nPIcKandG@aUaD0biFGR2BScdW3MaqtsCaxCt6O4zH9w08NOkYqA1W1wZ7Hd@kC9SFqGoa/LiddoyibeHGySRp1nQYRrwsSYEGSpqz220lCQbbwvOwoW1KV9JHGARdK6uAuJQ@moECjwH0pU6r4fXH7pBWZMconVZPsjuQBHL4CM8n2hAX3pPMVUBMpbZuJuUoe0Q10orYwPQ8PO0IehHpI0jyENieLtliQwP3JmNMywYhr2IUwpMC2jXIuw5593mCBvnGqPQ8QpJx7HgiG7Rr6SPQDIgKFmgMzNqBCGUQLB8BAaAMMQHYqrMdlomzKyuRKM@OUrrG1a38nnuxWVHCZAitjftw/cRljAdeoNXjPRrIF6KGQT0LefpAOAw@IVkBuwCT0xuqXLRx@b1BASw6JCRGRWN37sywqlSsdpxRiRD@uTXEUSmqB3s5rgDMt6k@bpfkJLMTCazsj@bZDiieIHSB6xR@OlU5lJTJ@HotSfD/3kyLHLlQVRRQxgKI@uKtogUkg8RIdl6HLbZTYZq@HWcB8i3AvUVI0RFKgaF4NvlY1b/wA68Bw59H/LNoJbzZPjTSJ/h2cWMsg25vjAeB4vEoXBiIDa38ABSUYocjP3WQCopi9Sl2x3LBiKEJUf80pVhGi2Oy2elThAetV9WzDBeO5uL4oFQYm8HTwHODRD4bNDzfcqBCvaFj00FDdCgCrskFjgAZJc5r4WiP7Us8OFrUDSUOY@TRWS3I@YgxHZxEd3FRWpxhbLpg6fq0STKzq7LWoM30IosRo9G5MnYALk6JCOGmiUd8uU6zbw4ApRPTZHjWjldKpbqgFY2bdLjOIwv4qndgQVdieylx7Vnq0jq3Uqd48KXidECFFluVI6hIYfPjk5niIJu@45yzvnVu8gHc2NxGb4/p@SQorUmg7OwLhC3hWLGeSbI0BCd5LPhuw2ObOwvJUNqN2DR@85nRNmINrNE31CdZLl5pdmHYIfrS540kzGBv6vlHRdCBB/CuBiLXFJvEK1HcnxqcfiCJQy8qdN6CioP4wxiYnP5hEegEXdy8gBiKJmEfA0Kz5W@7xlYMpf2IOgBqe9Cy8NyokVvCwwIAE7cda0HTEwLeZh@zjC7RVTJ0koc4dQNgYNVX5qFDGCTFcnijNlSMyvf6gFyB1jloQxhuUxXsh@l97kY3nek1Y2@2IcBhp0N5VRhvFv5LLvSCrQP5mYq@AYF5wHAJJhsxOQFgE3Jc5qCD9IvJObdLJEtK7CakJEMIgtQAhVQF/85DFjrhWYKA@4bHzxgUJ0xdXl6qdNTZ2LVU08NTjz28yDE17FqgEzupkTkYivtlLLxxTMCduRR@2Dle73l3QhdrFu9M@VOSOl5FLD2IRTteFDvHCzzUtzugI1LwbBKPGOrAogPBWzGxWoLzn15PXvn8V0L@UwrRawTCGIKZJKfJVhKAJZut82Tnsl0WARfUIAE41KLpe@Lpgq7/MvB8lzXsBDGcEa2A99@b/fOW03dQJ5H58Oosa15CP@bUfxXvQ2sCiWzzku26rjGNUXgcYyMDx6ak9rApdPsUAk7oZtgVP@vOmtSm9bnkkyA5dGrBPLKL559IV@uB8oMPMXzCwycQPuHhk1mmfra1SZ2rZOh1jcVBrsdjs/yYCGbqx7nmhwTOQggyKNZM4yAw5nTO7xq@rQql9unN36AeKz5jAE8MgeBmLFV7flY7q9ueeblVT6S6wOwyEQJqHEDX6kTTy3bgRur3L/pDx5vzsvG0NOiVBN7o1eoJbuC8gmUMKogYg9PLwgOuugOVjwNxhUAUGCCgHgaBqBrsjmJWvBwcn0mBwDg1eUZjjlhNIFMn7UsECT9QlzjpOWHDgOohQOgfFAnQhBDmtxx@xr0vHZ65eMmvH1ehY7kHeNBKtB4FSi40FS5rylRJIawUxUcTyI7qamWxKH44VEVtIShUzGtR/2H0Nz4Y/Q60i@XYE8PyDqMshZsKrsUCFUI0F6Iqq1ZC9QoYpLaMvulCz7XP9VPRW0M2WynfzOD5YBG8S7zSLxaq/Fac1w/tSZJtuRSwwrRSgSJOK7xZ8nbhk5QTPEjmiWRTnxFEei5AAEZ6aTJTJJuEk00qFS442GRFsssQkhNCcsKT8NiTFUjWRTKwnoK7YLF66qCd4sovGeBpvBsFNWgoM7zXD@eqX@IhUDiTKfKcyRziAsFDqGIjn7XqS3OvhZAOCa0FAMiINwC0@XU5JWlR4GlK8BbIKE5KX0bxN8EGXFYAg5EILvODEmMBk5ENDAq/nKB@ANqunKhJsoarzugvzb9y0vf0v9pNz/R8TG3eM51c@PtH8awjZUMNNKR9aOksCmS0ZJ6KG5DndI4I3izXc0Cra146LLZE2Qb/lH95cqrZd5qpgYHrQ/ASjeBK5bhvP@CUCLs3dEbGyMlmS9xosojtluXPbQaraztgmoQPSAVdr@2Ynh0dQaW2nK5teWYSL3HmKrtJqxX4WcxSWE8WTseTJDEGyc1YBM35ClXdRgOv9Wo0Yp7Z78RLwaJRfFWRPaNRCe1fcIXSg3gSQI@GMQevpx/Fb4eJZ/mKZKdW6zx2NBSBUchkl4EMa4H@D6E90GCY58wsRzpVFFXp5ihGh3L3nIHTBa1v7KkSpl4AfziDjQgZwyHhkmQGmrSl0IHO1EpiraQRF0k/@@Ck7DM9ZsSD9Po8gDliJJm7SGOkrLsku8bK7HgyP7@TD8f3JIzvyXp8yQpfxJmb5hUe@GFZZ2IzCBBxhkbmdjSw6CC32jfQmUMl8Ea9iid4bxTbtP6qjZjuQtRdEV3tAH8kgzcP3gLEP19F//UV6Cfff9/qM/Cuw5MpyJsBLguM0Vnsnj@5GYPoh/G4FFmSXcDaD94zL4iLN1UcoAoBaiwJLhsPRISGOQSz2wuO6fYB38LzuIzqBt/T2qoKD1yCk3uRZOf66ip60GibfWNqtmMiZjIE1y/xMRhsJK/er@Ao6EjoOdzWi0HfFQ9CoRtHovNIpRUsYyQv4vHVbMWjWAH30Eg5YXi4mn4YfkM04xBfhY9Wgx0QjeLhXPaFhcOfw@lwys/c7dPB4L4c5f0Pr0nceX07QYAO4uyR5Czb@DrxeRwLivQePUIQV50vMh6J6UPE0yZv1uGHkej2kkLlhhJV/FqW5s@PX17j1roaD3GFz5N83uj9WPI2pntvnguxGgc2E2F7H9aF3ICMKzJarVgYIvdZW2OOfUMmoB@N09krepXGEoEapCRJN7LI3Cb9Ii6hZXwITxxw@hyeCLBrjhqcofyy4ZiWuNuCUcjAGIa0FuEDSjpACVGRk1ygEYol@W6IfnUd5NlamWfrRp6tuTyDFjCfZSiS1JrLUtQCVs@6KuibndEK6YxBaDvDY53Yho/tGC6OVlxFrWjJSrLoRbQEAjlqRkv7MRDK0Xa09IAcXrR0Qo7zaOkzcMzaVvRNtOQ3C4zgwis57qG/EOH43oqW9mLxa2lknJuen68aLQV1CnHu8leiCJACyw1aI06x2Y4o5sg1oWMjpTLJkGO8JJpPNA6TpG8a/vmNEHSyPAbiGOcWRWYJps11GqEeg@cD3YZ/cvGSllwSvfn@0QGtaAqiYDYJsPHCaQg8qOGR6Lww4ohhKM1owBMQRLlZWo4RC/Vk74mOyB04lCp5Pn@inkr6QDtG4TWIXJ9lQteAiPR@fc2D4BX4fnhi4lV43kDHz44wwjnZ@BK0kKgvomsKhXU9j4uo/XAN0Vj3fCS8LNSPwmuJwIZkOuhwNDmHmQ2d4TyTUCiujLfCaWhQjjdK5N6FZCQVRMtcEUzeomQoGMKNP76uOKF0iNqcCMLAWrrOW1nQL5AsxqCZrAtpqrzxAQohmQMt3Gyd0xUrD4ST4nFxk6S@YlU35KflWZLkmheTkFjFI2TGxojnHhiv@3iwzIeZr37KCY61xBBAKGWQC5evzgfo7w7X332F2ifCQgbLFOvlXelN9XptL7uAeX@W7c0KxMAkexBfqhwFOcxIDtZBSDNfx2s3VHxc8sGVfJ5pAH1B2/fJFtgEt9Bt0bbgsFBLcC/mPc918DzXVxPqpkbSv1B9pUXFnAQcXvAA01nR1uPKC76sijGExreN/gdXsDtfweHKQ3hUAHeB5LyVu2ObVrnM2jaIbe6DIlUrMS7Iabo0qOaZJ4h7mroNpm3B46hx/ODo8cNvQKe7vb0dF330dIYftlocaw36cQ6ZFlAH/cESs0VP4q0JONmNw/F0Me/GmS3fkCVcWIMyYEAuPvuJNh4XsiwkzxfaLqTjcUMUFbDOZ83AmJNKqOoY2GVbgq4jIIg5im0ZAoiv3gK9k2Stxel@gEYDL2NtNKj7ajRw8VKjIXoxrBp/Rjz@88hGauy5dBkcv9ziUpJoOzx7cMSefbp7yk4/3WcHT/c@Y984esqe7T4@xW3NT57ef3i4x@C7//hkn0lzyyPxIiA0KIGuD8yWibew4flbWUaQ95zhlMud2F6c@58YA/ap0zJxmmrHMwb3evxFtc1RlafaB3N0imOYFl32NLBGuN6CbioCMxaVmzbtvMP1/gziNsGmHaDNO3DaVseCuBLavkPL9PwNYKxvQQ2CvPU3iSa5koSXEtHSIbo@DFdgXUJyA@Lj3A2AMfj6K7rv1vJ4ArOtMkG44PPBFDzdP350wnDj/N7R4weHp4dHj0/YwdExvD75xuHjT4Cehyenx4f3n2IQRXx09ODw4HBvlzw4AmmV4db1l2NvtBYFFaMTVVrnOPNN1xoHb/Oj3qjBs0uD9iB6LDq2UfpYRt96bbajZWnsofqC@x5pqoDFNnePP/kc@nxmvsIZTn8qmNYfyE89uhxrM812KDdoLFVob2XRXKHbU7Q4zUcMpgzPyjfLtEs9Ru4k84HTIp62ZTJ5D9eo4Ng338xObdkHDRltAGwE5S9YqTC64yIaTe4QyCrk1uo7ePYez40vIhQvmPSev9SkLBHFxFoZBIr7FQ5tHA/SyoEH8D146CLbkcsjsEzgwSOwLPdAVfQQ146wnIgxHh2NUTyzPPd4ORge0LQw2w487htkxRYETrzeqEoNFtwRhFv7@3STCR/loRvWDK9lWZTEo/h4y0e/zxuGye@XApnIpxJpbRvElEHYdHCqQSx749crYihwA64TMjojj8UqcZWd4uIg07b4HTLdvmHzJVCzpTvEe6yAh7dUxDJbK7h7hXaADB1iQLz3aR6PIN0DoRWa75sOUt6/kaMh1kjS/Wf@ErTbELh/A4FfBAwAUuYsnRb1VLTVFME4HcHKMc8BjsRx27fh@MDO7XHLnEsgVm3FXlqvX8cFkZNzdpK/TpGwgyp6bbqgVtJUZsdxoY2TWKXbKlAKtnrOcGTxOozNl4BmnKibg9jYsUFuLyrVudyQDos52o4dyrQJXLwi1yYw5fvkShzP584D8TW7uhA4Hzphvu4O0TGaeK3vbO4siZNIlyYOv4AiTHPlOPg5HREmXP@UZrLjLcPbzwqV6oP7Z8rbF0m8Ao2LBX7roL/oEL/AmJgXNA@a56MFiy7qXaKl@VfXeOMmphZr8IS0xFbuAwM7sGeBXXevUQ7C@HLjm/64QWbRnzzfvKnwVApKJnERpdeLzaRbktX8LJOUps7EEpCQ7ARkQdbHfJ8kwQzk9T3cCoO1UAaK2ChH0G5fuBhGiBC/dM1xBySLuJ9PVHcAP86qtKJidl0p7mwJ10fqeex@JVGNp2YLSliInDFfRCd9yFo8HlqWQv3VDXAP1oMD@f3@4AprsePdwwdBe7AW2gfhpiRWw@LdUgjW@4N9uwYs79x@IbBQ9uRqwLyTvAkt4PSAOZObkWA17focX9yoO2p7AAb7XhxBCYCGchvbNEXtn3Qb4wniYTAzhejk9MH@8TGTuX0CaUHuocnQFmIQYW@wJ7PVtpZNwk4NlKbAWA6UJ99nbkWb/1nXmJcSb4WoEDpIUtAjEBazi3k71oRLPdGzkApBq@9JIPqUm8fuypdBXk0AvgYbEJCdVVqogNLSYkZ452N54UXggm5JrhuH1/DTCmved@Otd@40DCi8Jsjo4s6S5fX3jOvHJT8frmCZr8ZU4DZo0tDfgJ1wAhkPIaKqztfgmmrxqxQX2XMFO@LTDhd@pec17L8/QxEjcSWc68IhsS6UY4Ea1483fTWHFiRiN2DgSk8RyFc0Q4Av4slnJ1yh8VmnF5vvgkDJxHvQ7oW5ApLXr8vBxdyxWT9ZCRTycFvbJGxqPpZ1HJ0VsMurI32Ma6Hzi@JhMSuQtmuzUv5hsuK9xFxOPs2XFsYPBMj5XC5zG@zFUvjJlb8vbN6HLMrP0WAI9v0MpDf1aHgfOPfwcdIPnzHAGtLxpfV@g1lICKrOkj5lruzUGYXxA1z4uBAgg0dM49Vyi7nG2WQBt@XQeY8Uhk5RbpQh1ISDgvJWc4P61@uzQ4F8a34bH54fb2wYCZcOXuOq/EeO65mzXXmhk1ZCXrh/dd7PdF2bovH9TAOEEqNtTGs329FuO77glZcKA2m@LVySjtidxJfdJv2xBsqEhhdVvE0SR/fKi8N7ilYOF/Xg8OE@26LD8DpzY5GyK8dDsmfDstchQDKYxiWw@6A9fB97JfgCDkkfJJCJdvPFiDbxW3EjioDWXKNbP8SyUCFbtcXa73gtw8ZjP5Lyxx6Tk3cgIY3C7h8dxJeNrKfLc@kBOW9oxyBVUlZUmZKCHw7oIqR5ELw20T/UYeFODX@l5Jo7wI2UVkjnixKVzk6OkoNasZ7calVkBp2vYQ@8sXvZPu86vYsO67Phy@akNX39irFclmUgL/0OPwhVy1dSdIrkNvwWWDFNnPv/Fnd1W20kSfqaeoq0hI0KpJKEbexGCLcAYasXgweB3RzAaiGVsLaFRKsESG2YM7MX@wK79/sI@yrzDnO1TzEbX0RmVpYQtvv4orlAVZWZkZGRkX/xlxrBVxzU9SSlVMA31ECxrOJzeOmRktu3@NC8Cg@JKS5VixeGC@FiNypfHK@clvvlQuniuH9agpPfaKk8WiouZfDhCa2iNMeIZv54dIo11ZW6hv1rheso@QIx7Rqi2DWEvrxtDruDncru64Q0DhsAiMC0rTcL1OUmyTlYs8H3JOiHNxktJssqcKyHDZI3x15BRfi0szwZ4ph2lzCjXsnSbjYa8/@J780VgqvL0YBTdEU5sJa67d56c8aNqcASBcpy3D016KwxnDhPBooh@ToRK@pcUbZrRfhO@g6IY5Tk6TB1kkrBpxCIal@u41MvCsJm6xOQwNWpt1xMra3xRarEalHAUjyYcjSH7DBROMUjFCD0c8naBlTBO/eI3T48aj7ei3iQLyyjGrGfDBvIe7xTRArMv9Vn9m/i8mtEACH8nOy5Ai3i1Dsv2kiK7yALFxCPLHnwh5oBbpXSKXNoLGBLfeUYOFuKM41QrSYTfZ@7ATmFVvSnW5Ar8tu9Ztj8vmRnkrCeWr9FoCV3KSet46cXF8s4xXKmmMnskGLuq9SApIuOR29DGlYTtRn2eoS00GIuJgce2b9X179k64@OUeepRV7Sc/fSc4n0QNIFqThXQAt8nGnVzZRKf47z3alUnC17r66y4s1LQD3dCmhLEuctfSlvFIwGjW6ced12pXClTVhLJOSclI8zel9SHiXKWAa36ceSrvl7Wfe8xTKR98dk/fj1dAeFbDyrbU2muDTod3uvZNGyKWCzFFFTKSmO/ma2k0GpfTD1dEI7OMj5ediul2MoS0Uz4/CYSa2v/ZgK9CbjVWYaDfFivDewZowRh0pc5xITbswOi1QPJz9yQDBMMJoyI3fdFJ7owhMHLHI9MtWKF@S9AU5Nmx7iZfhF3uKfGexJ5Ey@9OzEOcF8LI0X7@YkgXjSfZSaTabkbAJ3EfmoG/WFVSSuezINcfYksetIgW2dofhgdyAGf2TnCXeiMDPFPbrbFE3pOEPRsO9DXYjEO@9f@UXvdZP22Je9cKwqOGY02QvLSzi4I@5shMhOHIsmurq87EHryBu@G3ah1oFClp9D3RJDdFb2wKvBskfyZ/GkHdKpUKD2APkGBiJxQnR1jnvjodhBPCeaWiFx6Y4Cr9KfiECDxszTZXEzD9VVJFpTOu2fu0hIz8noAaWjy2YrDDzao0W0@/GkqR0Z31qeDr8RRBijJW3V8/5y1W39uvka@twXxcLTokOya60OLgRPn8UOVkQkk7BcoG3s8@Izz3N0wy3RDecAMKt2sNC/J94Mr8N@P/QqtGJwxog2rVE4vA7bgefth1YJDLhgZWgm4Yc9uBq2RLhDm64mMSO8hKOsqMOIw/CL9VnUxS3WlWU9KK1ibTN19XW3DQIaj5POANphVlggTIDQA4UuwhERZdFXSZRY96xx4b3LBQRRRA3EOXF0E5YM/cGo26KeYUmW1yNQogaJK@u3pzCh@lq9JpyDg1kIwD0mpoBBwKiSvoSDp5XmfwgHpRtmdOxN0zN5mv0GPFZouIfDLs2@MYG5V7iYgzt18MGbWl3V97YPPlT2q4qe3@3vva9tVbfUxhHruKEo58C26s3eDs0uVpsuWvM9@pCq1KlkihO8yu6Rqv78br9ar6u9fVV7@26nRtAI/H5l96BWrWdVbXdz53CLte8EQe3uHaid2tvaAWU72MtyraaYF5dTe9vqbXV/8w29VjZqO7WDI65xu3awi8qg1a@od5X9g9rm4U5lX7073H@3V68qNMzbqtU3dyq1t9WtgOqnOlX1fXX3QNXfVHZ2phq692G3uq/YSMBp5UaVsKxs0BEWNXE7t2r71c0DNCh@2iTiEYI7WVV/V92s4aH6c5WaU9k/ymqg9epfDikTJaqtytvKa2qcl/kKVahfNg/3q4h/BErUDzfqB7WDw4Oqer23t8W0rlf339c2q/WS8nb26kyww3o1q3AzGVdNMIhalE7PG4f1GtOttntAa8bhO9g7@NTJH4gwhGWFim4xgWEGgdYSkfb2jwAVdOAOyKoPb6r0fR80ZWpVQAVYVGweuNmoQiLigdtMtVt9vVN7Xd3drCJ5D2A@1OpVnzqsVkeGGgwyjoh1qNJDbjX6ifCSR2JWz3BulrtT1bZVZet9DZjr3MQB9ZrmFibb5htN8wARcx0hSncAmUHzwhWsdO5/ug4RgPK@RGa2jMZGTNrc26rSiqyDVaXihENadV5OhVJy02ilsYn0mghZ0w7Prs4b3X5nAB9TW0wEHxfReRa3nvi4/OHE@8LlElq@wgXS6UbjfaVBB916o@Fnv6VkAo2vldBi8C/l8nUbERMfJ28IflZXhe5rCUKtP9GKTjbUgwICOYX6T8T0rXkR@iqfb4e6GJz3AdiIjiJRm3yCKoWmRnZ2xA0VcZUsmeD3rmYHLpgx4INWA3JSWEZypkFE//q38YssDs4Hmp1F3JXP4xDLaHR/D001UgmHROB/OiJBt8NVBlEY/nqeKbjV4cwfnA8G7YzvmzKcd0TnwPOM/5XiZ@H5VPHcdHlGltXOOox@ZM7dvIWx@mdNMqX7JRhyyzL41xjxj2@wkZgPkJpyVSys1kLLzBMpDoukrNKhLeBewZ2MPd/bys@1DzjNFZaflaa@v7HfZWzBXhCBamnBO@Zyp/zz5lQy0ADjWBxEkq6OkJHPO2WMvYnNfEMZPyET3zPAa/WnkNd1IgltZK@aPbdOrMbD7tjFnubh1/uVtxuH29s0dQLbZy@fv1gpeTbs1s9Z@T1CPRzplaOOXdI6Tvs0TnJGySZtfHikOPG2Y/ZnBs7nkRFB1k2n8UfEebB2G0lLJkxkaG6E61r6MNFLhaBDSnEAjkee4deZI1MzQCbRVB@tuWiOeYvfpL0S84A2ZulNuNfG@AfYdvibIW4bpBlIsxjH1yXOpdMFz3upbWMqyocbDtyDLEHK8LGEcbM0YFEX28/Cu5bfNG87vRiJKSPGK3c7lyQkHk1joYxdRV9G9juOM6IFwBw9jL78rPmNHo90gDsOd9eMRpVRnci4bUtCTh0Lo3WjjzXk0/UyddGTJ7amNQUpv6@R4rGnxck2MIgzGhiVUxgVltUU4JKNIzJdJVvA/rjgq8/CqQjeATglzbH6nTh3VnM0lJKJH6LfTVQKJbBskBOh2o2twzNZjmwcC0POBJm@ix4M/0@kyQz4a3TiJOgxtZwggN9ESYYqtKLjKxOle2MUDY52I6am@@koBnPndswn2zCtvRmLfw2RQPfOxHw44rCHncwMAoDJIdhwx681SfvUpKPTjylfF4eepN@6uMwovVaYpeIe3NzKaZa3XVmjW8GLr3yRNTkV7lBR9aMc3M541NORaeoorx5HKQHnm/gf@UUWgNgBz1z6SaxWpzmroEeZmQd0qCVnwWnbiEm0Lb17UGu3qJwQmYm5X2u@DKEI9Drwud9Ovv1joMQ8NxlxkVdidcBR8BASHMdkLD46ZN0ZG2L2QsB53GZhCC4IGd1ggegJdA7VF0NTmcdsKIJKYqvDOM4gpls/INLysnpjsWfJJDjUYn/Yl2D1oUi1TI5AAnxoDF13@UC9bU4I5d63NVtYLL9YH2Rhu4jKRCyhy@MylNZgMKStYxPtJhyz3YkfqA9a6BD2o6uhjl9I61l3qCUSZtNP1WDbJKd3XmYkhjujFnVH8FZoB8wf3KSLEBaiEp5knFtRGWJew6PrRujYHS8VVWYtTlkjmnBYUibimlpRt7eSSwiqQ4aGTMFuZA8XbLPJ9UDvYIffzWD4K9Z@bIH67bBtI5M6IFkWKJ1U63OMx9ZImn45iFiiQV0BCYilRFEEadZQldboF5qdtF1TKo6Oidil3JI/Xo9lUmMtRRXFjKtrJ@ZbyVFngkrLOjSoDRZaXH7OqMw6cN09eBjjaKFJtbVKnfTtlLIqm4jyY7N1xJPMm/bpCE9ayF9@HGH00BfouPUWFAhjzwq96v15jvGDTcGHbjhsuzJR2sm0m5cQv/HRZ9BnXjSiQx32r9UcReGETgCtfHecZxiNzE@DT/3G5qDXPO8Ouk06pyGG@1hmPDxO@BEddj4c3ER8zw8ntJ1M7Un8LPFlJAwb3q1esuSE5opG4WXGNVMYDSeVTxImgiXnMAKMr11k/r6cjpFmyzx7Hhfykv6nbI9X9EsPln1anFVYNPoAoCe49SkLCvEhHbFjkuN8WrqX4exLGRwcz1RONf0HLPYSGP9AJGI1TAJjg8w9swS3ETiZPYjxcXucbXMMwiECLYVbIa6liTL8OdvEBbc0i7yCpcCqKr4sOEVFizJGHEI8TB4m9/KLPxl7QuA70C8@ncUtsxiBp7iOibYUyXlFRxklXNg8sMtzNM/ENIt1z2kV6iWANsbTUJPJk4eowZY/tCnSYfbucSVGZIYOPrg6LtOgKacx8bGoLKgFn@N2YAtSGWUKDzNs@DX7WR78UOKK5AwT06aGnHGQfohULaIS7vKcMq91UZaYyl8fMcvL39prUwQszzI5c@6szaTMzoU9ULqyvkKtNRjSZJyaop429ViIRoPLhW@k3oNzx8zIbLNo3fL9rxoCC7OVabFcbDNpyxM8TkreND5TTJOkGFuaEQ/h@MrPls2niTguNzDeyo3JV@jwEM1iuym7qNj@bsvYx6J4DYtes9DYIcW4I0hpyX4/blDDGw/PIBqmHK8aPGM0MGU0JvLogJoik6XSt1OIuU/jPkWPNlEO9baJdm7/PEjUaSM5E/LUJCWCXIKeCNwOp02aly47ML5AmDjZ4dpJym44x9kJq/KKuTMEGUaCAMSuOMzFciiR4MadNcVHfDtAJ9OAtVARMxE9rbsWDjbovyUYR@XXwh1t8dCY5IqnJYE0tpDoVMG5vgTJ@JvT63FjzFDukYKG@AxS2Bbdm5s@fXurvrctlI8gSGlO1pa@hSwa46slwob@uUmNMfbAcVW6ZGJEJQdCg6cGGgt0SjnvhXJcxe6vOxSOh3WDHkZ0gJDPGfws6RII571SsNRGkXF7giy@JreMNl/l1qVIzFDyDvLroShbXT64EoBQMKby5SJBQFhTxh5KAQ6943JeAlHdR1SwXMSwpI8cFTW285yRDqLqDM@eOzkKs3L84MLIzQRCG4vZeWJEaM8yO0sMhRa6mbg4OV7Mbk@cgzbEhveF4tQVuleSNLQ9JwSkR8bWzijHRZUtaA7mxGfP/USi5W9O/aHgpBamU4k@FsPjXHE69WUhkZqodnk5WTRRkujhu7UmEokUvouwnRW@749dU9yQ59Ym1DlkJHYZ2j67j6PUDc5twb9Hao2dss0ew8BzPcPN8ashV6wkgrJ/OQC7WmCVAWK3f3drjWWqwUTfFcBx6YyzS0YOhLxjTWGpR7Nw0jWR9myAAnOmHXTU@4Pt7UTY17OJMTS6CIfPC4UCmPjMDX5vbKshSuoO8snc@c5Vr5e/vPlp@P4sz3M/7rTvRYNVc4IOqUtoUETBYHguN0MAB8qK3DntyIqz/lWn417BAA0lOo@6TXLqaAiKF6CuNXp5f8ACIAapF9hf0EC07xdlR99NUzaaGopRQ1FpmARfp4z2jMiDDx3YZ1tNFQPDxGysmWjd8svrn7GC4GYT7iwOX@x/js2TU2/CXm@QVR9wUzAiBczdTRfY3nYLFCQLNIzs3XsVcTzarAqvuz3HrxhZXF4HOLMwmXsmTFx4xMbfD8@r48tM6vhjipYVavISmrmE@NRZlTpP@TpY/DeAFT4ktL8p90XzMtNiOk1npqVej@D4iTB6WszOPPsksvgsE9M0@3puEHU2ugEHa6Cm@7wXMLHsuXu5JQ9kt8RNnYyLHdCwIDA0Toi58m0l4Gr2502L16NO59tmRb4GQDr2D82IchPK902IrAPgEaiHH9ETUbT/LUfDensqoIhscHBZx/15BwUaKOB5j1vl324ylUpFzV8uLalKZYMecjlV2aioLXzY2FBb9L6B9yfl5efPSzLnbvmf6eOG@XinNggGSziXWp@GW/RKaWX4jcFaG108ny/PZ0vzjfLaeinKH1c24NZPT//8@3/@8z/@K1/RL/@Dlw1@Of5oMwVBkJ9vfZ5/clfC@/HW6cL82fH85enCeQlc9i@OGj6ojXLN2Hw0GJ55aVkFnK9sR2rO2Rx9RhdV5la/i@bwV5pdVlW6FeXT@mskN0fxHJtuhc73EH6UZ3SEN5cOTB/lCYk0AZ1AHE@90wphgEfrDVGScIEdqJQX3YoR3CMcjM1gtSppHYmH96zXIXxa4kgK8MWlFSvX7UdhHxLwa97zSvM8r0m/3VFD82/@49vofGMwVosnGbVYUItZtZhK8U9x5Qf66s/nu/DOlWx0HEilspQSqxZgZqiiLm/0@PzAd@1Mkdvz5vnKHkAyYSo4s3jBZe3pj51l5MK16Nybw6WZSkQkrGRCkfTn@f4ddctnynGXSrja8EahoU8xXJmjUbH9iy1QMxJDgLjmCyHI6oCqhKaPPZLxlDdfdF97fJsQAwZZ919v87jHB1qL5vva5jlxlsI1R2w@L1@xNpbEGZrRRorUHyPAChU5ThbYk3AhveCJlbfTSm6meGG77dPMJ7YOk3BkbNOl0F@VwwRize0Sbr6v/Vq0IbeoV1Sqa9UrTlWpadtv5TlFLq56o@6ldlfg2jGgPtva7mQkoUcZkMCRmP2r90cYCwpMpKipbpHLsiaqPUDTZST0tWs6dbAfiObIIUL@Y4bG9u3U2Pbz7CVi2EF4gJGypnydZrcX6agrQyb2eXN4htsBmx2@UG0kejOW5@Ga1CmMBx2LdMCQ2eQ8Hs/UlPTlsHl@0cyq9O7gYNic1GjZop3PqBX41EKEYAISGHy66lnNMwhLi3SXMEVsU9hyCJcX9Cb6ejTp25T1OUGXmqGgw65gECTYiSkZ3ib6aoqOMVf/gU5wUb43eVttpJ5ieeaFpZGGlHLdZniY3Rs6nqnBHTt24KQ8QdWOTMMLutAVFtoLVvzSTN5DjABdd0p7AWpXhJUfUD9Wp/Ow30wsTpc9zzj650tK1kWMZ76KUqyRPHPzaTG@8Q5Y0T7yYzIKhKxNJpyRN5fJzJ1E@jq3tLuOcJBva4ufb6quvYCOLzBjzxB12O/KZDm1QsV3YASqxpb/BKHTa54TfpOb5gSseJLOvHqU948/nvRPFzMn/duT333GRE/JZpXNqbRWZpsZS48VWhnz2cSrsUqLTKjBk34yw0lfiQ@LQwJCJJ85/pg/vc0TQidp3Dt/khaCJLoMmOS/XF8e4PP30EwnscinvTl/0Tedn3lV9BWtrfyLPpQPvvwSFuZQyWJ6OucMOwSK/XR/uxKXkyj/crnwbLn4jE5C5@E4NwyvsN7moquzcExbiQjHWVp6Tn5PcEOCEHfjqFmij2Nqp1xrIr4nkXZS0lOoHuZcj2fZisoEwhOUn6jM4VLh4uLbPE0oH3HgzypiOZOXY0GJ6aDDfRmsn9HgAvU0I8xr094hwpGwMhAbERah5gDZXL7yEIf6ZrgssJ9ToDYRu5WBUPfm085q0R/0c3qz5gcLJWyi4TXTe1l4WZgeo/eGaGKEzuvN1MIjVVx/9eIf/733W3qUXl/OfxjS7yj9W3rlZVoe6YHenpq36/R6eg3ZVu7SkzydgenxxT/@l8qv/0RwkDJZo3/rzw2slUl6PVfmIrfp9RV6KC4vU73/97e/URvm5cSGu1jnG1nFiJUMRTabfeZdSlc1tFKOpQvxtMKOWYAhFoZ0NqcXGEaNl18WWEyX1lYV16GOfGXsUfQSz4ZZIzYVEkmGsaegnZEUKKOCnIA0JhQd5dhuGLMNMG@MpvrlcbAS0QngF23OYau0phuPI5gMzcuxiDowIzXSeV4e1guvUta8YzVlbEpKZguJo52ea18@Lf0/)

There are 3 dialects of Wierd: [John's](https://github.com/catseye/Wierd/blob/master/dialect/wierd-jnc/src/wierd.c) (John Colagioia), [Milo's](https://github.com/catseye/Wierd/blob/master/dialect/wierd-mvh/src/wierd.c) (Milo van Handel), and [Chris's](https://github.com/catseye/Wierd/blob/master/dialect/wierd-jnc/impl/wierd-jnc.js/src/wierd-jnc.js) (Chris Pressey).
Slightly newer version of John's interpreter is available [here](https://github.com/jcolag/Wierd).

Chris Pressey presents his JavaScript interpreter as an alternative implementation of John's Wierd, but in fact it is a completely separate dialect no less
different from John's Wierd than Milo's Wierd.

[Answer 136](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142576) is for Chris's Wierd. This answer adds John's Wierd.
John's Wierd interpreter is very buggy. A couple of bugs related to handling large input files are fixed in the test driver (see also [this PR](https://github.com/jcolag/Wierd/pull/1)).
Bugs in `IF` and `SPARK` instructions are handled by avoiding those instructions.

### Explanation

John's Wierd has a bug in `IF` instruction, so the starting code that gets Wierd on the first column was changed to not use it.
Also, I don't use

```
x
x
 x
 x
x
x
```

because it puts two ones on the stack, but for the main code to work the stack must have any number of ones except 0 and 2.

```
#                        line 1
…
#        -[
#       x  >
#      +    ]
#     #     #
 #{{{{]~*[~*             line 10
    x
   *
  â
 /
#
#
…
9
2                        line 35 == '#'
…
x   xxxxxxxx             line 70
x  x        x e     xxx
x  x   bxxa  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 xxA cxxxxxd  x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
x   xxx        xxx
…
```

```
                              [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
A. 90°  both   FORK
                              [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
a. 135° left   GET (1,1)      [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 35]      '#'
b. 45°  left   PUSH 1         [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 35 1]
c. 135° left   GET (1,35)     [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 50]        '2'
d. 45°  left   PUSH 1         [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 50 1]
e. 135° right  OUTPUT         [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Chris's and John's Wierds are separated using T-junction. In Chris's Wierd it is `IF`,
in John's Wierd it is `FORK`. When TOS is `1` Chris's Wierd bounces of T-junction; John's splits in two threads.

The bottom thread prints `2` and the last `9`, the top thread prints the middle `9`. I wanted to `SPARK` the top thread into the middle of the bottom thread code,
but John's `SPARK` instruction is very buggy, so I don't use it (which makes the code slightly bigger).

Numbers are hard to form in Wierd, so I use `#` at (1,1) to get number `35` (ASCII value of `#`), and
then reach to lines 35 and 34 to get `2` and `9`. The same idea as in [Dennis's Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142785).

Numbers `2` and `9` on lines 35/34 break LNUSP, it is fixed by moving LNUSP header above the numbers:

```
1     ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
9
2
```

which is then collapsed into:

```
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2
```

### Chris's Wierd

As it turns out, [online Chris's interpreter](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia)) has a bug: CSS from the Wierd code spills to the surrounding page. So polyglot doesn't work in that interpreter since answer 258.
This is the minimal example:

```html
x <style> body{display:none} html:after{content:"258"} </style>
```

I don't want to fix this bug, so from now on I consider the nodejs version of Chris's interpreter (in the test driver) to be the primary one for testing Chris's Wierd.

Answer (score 5):

## 317. [Z80Golf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Z80golf), 14544 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_#          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>    xxxxxxxxxxxx    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99>ss<!--
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
X#  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa






















































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::gek:>Ex Cr Uithar5"3.c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]pogr34*61  prstd6,1 ,8R ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on;z $/op>s'0}e}equ7+?4[0]tfc;[ ]5:ore>8 8"r"
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ7Hup291skezbVwJx0QWgAFQTqEJXASTQbHZIml2tNfbOejSyQ5ZnfGXNelZeT8R4J3bW8o49E2HvxwnHfPIPaD82Nhwb1j/QnnMyq1AgAZAtjyM2NrZIVOXz5MmTJ0@efLcMr//zn0fwYc@cwaw3cMZsbHpj1nGtc9NV2YMZu29YXk7PSBKG2nV7k6Fpj72yFGEaY97YcMdsYNi9idEzWQRcdTa3d63B2HSTzDNN1jIHzgX4ZxizzQt2YLetDkBiY@fMtK03pgt@WcYemoO3w7dj1naGQ8PueGzkWvaYfHOMPTPA0p20z5jR8sau0R5bjg1eecae2wNj2OoYjIKPXJNHKjAA1T6jOIs@RcaeOK5nQgpO2/Q8Bx1L4Gi4lvN49@nH18JrafaxAUiNBub0WvKaxl5Yptu5HkNnn508enTdNcM@VRybPbqJkpZlu5OxczC@Dj/HdnumbTBdLan6dc88EHNsDorpYnrBC/weWS6UpiFKrTwvGXsybJkuEF8U4YU17qsQ4cThBGeOPZgxcwrAAMcuBDPHzMLSYrl0GkPC/7HZduzOHDw4mQAH4JrD0XjGFGY7ggfAy3GZNzLaptIxB9bQGpsdNrAAO6crsPEYFDg7M2cXjgsFr3BWJES8kdm2uhZGETnwJGS2h2Zr0mPOZDyaAHoe61ie0RpAsNaMdcyuMRmMk6wFfkA8cr/om7ZAybJ7mI8XcxeEYEMV4NhvakAbazBggM4ZooNJe2wbPS7QHYO2TMLS7CCo/Tm5AJIx8PzcLya8kAzGe@Y6PdcYAqN2TKLBZwfPmNd2XLDBD8PyWrAOTNsYs@1tFt1/@jDKagEZVbclBSStskvGWMT3ZOfGYGJ6bGjMIG17DJWLOVR@fgwJgrPoRrTMopkM09Msm2VZqGxFpufSDKpECQxQa/WMBr8804ssqwHf56JJTKfrGj1rYHIoPWfQRUAF5Fg9x3R4p7PRJPdtUxoFlimyfIEVcqwA7xIr6ZAIQswyrZSDXx5@AKEEGGjwy2R5SgFbIDtBFtge6xpDazDj0EcjBN9mOY0VACKgqQFkvQgQSjpCWHzC8MZ9IGzfOAeQysA6Q3FhBhIDSysFn9TWVopEFspGnqTXNwcDTBUIBSTKFVkBUs1DprOQMtBRL@p@5nt9yj7hVUjDD3AsQI6LQN40UCqNpCrAD@wghnSQNzoIFx3kha6Buw7mDEKFcHnwy0NZ5QPS6h2iLUhXiKshMVGgaEgDiMag6DJZBoWXheLNYPHmMgzwBAQKeQYypaixYpYVCwzIVUozIL0GyGDZayDLNEBCQ2BQpBqUqQaIaMAsGgDVMjkmheiqZdAf4mYgLpBAy0KcLJihXLQ8/iAeFLwGSWqQpq6X5qwFuOk5yGQuQzyn56HwCuAHxNIBVx24RQds9SL4Y9wiEK6ILFnwCWEMRn0DaQElgIwMrAYEyQFOBBvCg1kvZDhLUeiWObba0pUEtYq3gGGJ40sPlAAgTZjBsAEFBpxzTyyQgHEQSIvCauKZA@AikCFtA8zItlDbUXL4cKyxinIWminTOceGlKr/QjIeiYiWi60oyKuO6boMw0Jj6yVJmHiTlme@nmBbO8erC9LJBMHaNaxBgABVHWNM7QB8ox6kN1tEu@s6Q6pfQxQWA8cZrRC7IJouENAnzoU5R30uuYzRaADyHNxNIMTEGAAyFwbpA6QuhFPlCEEkjNfuWwCQkgK5arlmm2gvsg6xMyCBF1EsM712L4NQHoSahQwbOSBUPYxjTwaDMjR3ZptlaqmOeZ5CF950LDYZiIPfmEB7KEC0DGjLqTFFLAJI93SVmqkTv2Q9Z7iYNS5eDoKs9y1sAgYXxgxKrwuSxZwaQ9A4GDbrNjTcQ@AYXoJYEh5veA5Yx7Gj4wDKhQvNK2Q6yAmAHBBNxtbQBH3MgShY4llCGoUbYdaaASsTtbIqqWMck2uEUqXrhOIO2ZADryzQsHUmbaQapm3ZxEHQIHjUWtUALlc6VTRAlXNNo8ODoXaBGIX0I2jtTCC6UAXaBAg1FNP2QNvxVGahWggM33O6wGPURIOqAVHn6bQp75jzwGmqtlWJKI18MzwbMIu1RyMG7qCfAFqP0kVoY51XFnsDnoO@xwbtievO2HQEBWANIdS47XS7wLRvzFEfQLBhh7VnbaiVkEtkGqnjkARqj65lObBtmhDGNiHbe8@@znomUBta5C5gSpw@z8BoRFkgUhg2b61tAyiFWWiPZkQWABPE6DqOiu4dx/SIR0CbCWo8JuaZPaoRUL26cxk0RO0DmBM0AhtYFgSOqFUIHxOUlmYGkxKF/7FpQ41pAzNCXYfiQ310l3VB9w811qjcGe22ORoL9nBIill2SKE5fIQKDbkqApjq9aXN@6CLLWAgQVDJ55xQC26ckXBFRZ/0LANFrOhgQJtum4EKy7hAGcxuJA8hzq@lLr/EMAsYvJRX4DCimoDaHcmGyRglCApFq91HEThGIUNaBlQyd3Iz@@AWTt4dMqUbpI3YaCBtJDUVOCEeq2Eo8BvcBKSOBgirtuCAQRccbgFteMMlkJ0AyUEn7KqmDBVk4W1Ah47tLIEKxAzgYpBFHyoLYsZjlBrGIGBGqi7eQhmhnJ73fbH9gqZzNHJcqBlc6MxQkvEiC3GXw/spsaCJiEO/ebFFhZYiiu38eMz7XKMB9IOoimFNBX3SAEkBQoz3AEDmOTzFEMJU6wmWwO@CJD5nJmhCbdtEldRwZxwIZA9aZUhoxizXBTF4jm0Db3r8NkQlPoWmwOh0ULIiOajeX09cRY7em7Ss6fVuRhsd1VeedG64rIs9DBd0DahEsWjXi8Yr5E4xQ15yyhmNUxSVv2UISIFUKPJYFzot0BA8AkFzPLPbMXmhislJJk/G3aIcBwNG5KoZ@6oxGl/H7hW4IdMMz6Bek63CetBqKwq8FXQjTNAjpaKH4YJ6AZUQtOxSqdMy2FuQHi5TpnsUG9VC@mpqNkjLtDtBWoIQiEs4vypPwnPbZFBCrRrmAINTzqmRWCDgHSlBEWVwSKVE@4kOpORxP1JnuOPEpuEBFuMaSJxdBio6NAAxQsYCncNqW@Om0FLu3fP1lY1qFZgNlCgQm514WLn3x1FUkNQQWCUlRCSijp3jMdaNWBzyi4GvODagLQGnVmvsctx3ocaR/UqCQEBWyUZO9gkryvmpdTbpXC9oGx0xkIy1DnQlqz2WKxI0/rw2VNdRNbpAVVD@o0hVZF6MT6BvMC@5YoHKIphreqj1VgUqoRKOIQaCV5eSiEcVbnOG3pu1B0Il4Cao7FwatQD9M9FTDwRRUugEfqW9UVM5EKwOHA57tnvySVXURe6Zall2ecFh4LSNATlvYnDZj/v44MHR7tHXm0tgDKxW@bpDysoW89jUTqZKz56ksqpe3gzDmAN@2FwPGyMuhpEl4c0UZxpSlWZtaFymPjkPjz69ThLQhJAclAKY8XdNpeFhQOmSWobXv9YIs14iAUkGUfywTDlgPszAgKijv@Hj82zy5g0W3nWkRsIdMRtMDA7Ad0wd2H48FT2vKWC@V6vLW0SKC1qoZeP459wUDunj8zFqzdeRIVU6xDIfHz7aP6oS2L7hnZmDgUJBUt4YdCnD7ajA84NJx5SWhQHxB6Y2S6hzxFGfJlyXErjdXiDwvGzZCvgAALs4qsOUwdDPmtcH3Peu541clXbAAWQnCNf1yrA@1P5QREN4YBPXxp7uslaUPOaNVeC0tMUKfBebrXYuZxaypXCz1Z6n2QkDHZJSbDm@3uiC15mnoIs61yKFWi3QP358A3GPlEjoCig@Zt6AqZSWN5Cw96JYLOql9qCH5gxM9QVJPJnJ8VQq6g98qm2P@pyh8PtTaxxLx/lXi0NYSH1390B/6AcWA3U0gEGdBuyCY8vkdnGioe0Bj9jOwOk5bAvicO3QTxDUppXZ3O059o0SMtARsxrBmQuQvzheY4ygrbHeUMeRYoW7q3zWw7C9C5DSWj6DRCIKEagUhVdfGecGkGue7@ODb@xDI6Ll0unAnKYHSBCKQ@RCUzvkSg5MgYRUgc/SDAazGDdqu@@hhKYRMNNC0AURd@feSx1JYqqppeGXovRV5wbFXzmza6wFLpy1wBAi2cHTZ48Pnu4/2f38dKzncgv2bLqUB8JBei3QhdQ@pxvW1i1eNTFbCC4CdcPF6gVSYAIdFH84fOK5ILhVDKJyBFZwDZ//iX3V6dtRL349Mxfoq7yy25yFnmDl40FFROhodwbYGXH5tBm258g//fF45JVTKajl/UlLhU5r6lXbGRi9FMWDhmEwSGnYdTk4xHENb1kMQMabmTwGH9MC1WFGA4fGYOhA54Wm4lA0sBgHT4NVA6vXh74wzteZblwNOJhyk@pADwH6yqkgbySAyQa0FV@/nGTO2l/R9CLnay2tZ1OyH2yh@kPYja4JXacYtFZAivg1Kzu9d3qPzUBKI6TrQCJM3RJTNtgWDBgokjRYiv18nzgkLXCYFGUF0ej1BAdxQUqlculsQcvnUtAtg24a6KwKDrUpQ2Pc7itjRwF4itOlcYMQF3a9tmF31S1h8JEFve8jyGqm/sXpqd0ABf30HuGGE2H1WaOuNeIVdjPKlggfrwD3LmQPedd3AN4lI7AmfdkKedYxboqzjkG1q8NS4@FItDnKiD3ZBUXqjQPyumOG6x5GSIU9U1sLYVMY@F1qyYDQAKNK@EJKpaBCQUsLrJdCvBRQelE9BM4BuRWKwOajGTwffPo5JEew0418bzlRj8bqUa/BQVJvBESkMeY2SmkPxwfH0DoGnI9SGgoXhTS7MKM4fG54fJASIolJRz8@9NUCCDQYHwxE28FkKzABxaLuOUgO4CscLe3PRxmx0w@cBgkSTjj4ABqETZMGPZAzEJlnZJdnhKdELotZOrOdCxuhtUxWVFrWmI/xOxMXJ/OsTjhvEDyj8zAAjTIXkus069cy23yUlUemXEAn0GBDc@jgUAJoVyQKTMqCwWcMsS/o4UA1VKu0ghMnAF9h9/dAirVNPl6kDLETBSy1z6JjN7WrfCNlKG@Am9foVpj53fAENhX6iU8AGokMZrBplESMgJJ24gwp0Asab0HPB766K41m4z7kGDhMNqrOyLSv9/l4jzAWr9A8azQKAt@yY5fRjY2NaDlaiybBtAOmbTTtoCkBph0yKWTCcCqaKEaSTOhbpxjo1ohe1X3I03gDeWCKmsMbaxQz6uVyppE06pr46viNQ1EA5SG0gh@AE41Xq2iMx@XaBU7VgP4eyvse8s5x27VGggRfBYWA2wUNMkQE6N6jNu@aFeybrqfIsOpCp9FEFTPmRk/r6dPG6eVpJ3F6FU1i7HjFqEL/EITXODZUe64zGYHiVs@WFZBt8Xqm3Ki0qtF0dCsWKyoDSMiIxz8qxhMGp3UsagJPxU5Po0BSQZ16u@8SvGlSj8cDQgEeXQt6GYNBLKpeFiH9VrwRT0QhbjyaBLFcjUaBLm0kgkeZxhEBzkSPrCmQEiomNHHhOQUSkDQnhdX1G@aoP3PDAYJRN9CycQR9PhkPlYGkeFhKvuHxwwrdQk/f13t5OFBucfAO9aXRjEt3iWN6mlpYGOK3u@dKd@iMjdRnKnSa1FBzGd2IphQFWkLy4ZAo208sD6uwYZvOxAuPNC4dAMXUwfWkPwFh6a@aSQJXWSPJbPcdFt28D9BZMM2DTQnOWCl83ssH0Gmr8EMhiloJTpaAdkHLSSyQi7jUhI/KaIQEFz3@2HwuP3qtBqlVKA5LY0JWz3ZcUwGSQAyJFn/QUiGpxsSKkgMa@boxLyF8qUnDjrdlgkR8NHAMoi0X16H5oNEwFB/65xDlyOxIA5AfXRCPKi8L1@yktiSanHXcPrQQkBuUxHpQWkPhkXK8UUcdTyGqFMMGN@zJe3egdF6wjq7r@XauW/b9kCuA2H0oJOyV2tDF9b0UDTzjopD3@bCQ30d/evhwn4@dUGOLzSuOozWHTmcCeqXoNx2Zdi/J9oGfLNsZWkAGP/6bs8GR44x5Lx8sq0ZmeKfZGk4GBo35XB@WWRuv7bScAQ0FrYs6Dz9xPWNg8EEo33f3syeg6z8/Oa6q5VCglHE@XJs2jkMuT5bT8yA850jTrP70kMcZU97Mydhu@YvRUMwIjzx6TMRSNCgj372A7n6VwjkU4V5E9yEuQwNdWYwikDVwFAFLFBCXpuGKHuF4qaWv0H1lHywIp1E4rjjOsb3UdHI/H3e7C84Zcj5TUDQN5s5ZcuZL1Bb6iGGUcjwQrldbCBMGlKcwwbK16@GE8AqWGPTNgT@DeASKCc6SQds@QPUJ@iaoifO1YyYo0iOcDCEJjVNsrA26pndj2ALq1EjhoaXIBtUTaMNSqLlImykmhrgrVFNsR0xNelx6OtC1p9GT7RqfsMauk8t7bSk@@L7ZBBDbtYq/mmhVMEwpGg2CEVTCDWJQNmna/kZWg0UYHo2pSxSlInkp6DVM9bRyOi3sN1IeEaHL5NPT6Udp/XPofOCar817qZ5ZweRWUovsfBy63QexwRLTRZJBOUzsrjPoKHzSC8qf8e4SFoRYahCsOiOBDy6W6y84s3ARi1gYCOIytFbtBtxrRVe7GSC0ui0ABLXhkr09S56/ZXVowc5VbzSwxg12pY6dZh8zP5649vV1cFyldF1j5klipUqV7R59/Fk93eAQpKGBE1lFXlpTfxkl6MGg9@BqVTDhepuxNaaGnRYWWJhfTQWkpjTnAegDDJ5AhQUJiRwh6m/Nt/O8dE3oeMZMxNybDZPMjF@p3YExHps25y0@m7ia3HzaRyRTpeR3xBxCmaVpogUUTQv9AMUKOz55uH90pAKHerHoPk7IlKHaGe0@6BurMu1TMpz5MvuoE2UfYZw49sIlqFLQmWiK@MC8FWBu6E5A6igKeqYbA8c4zqW0wZmmrygiV7gEgXDVVHtMNAqAxcw45ImAlZfi/9zmPSeBZ5lFWYIoCeSO3SsDba24OrGt16oH7QapoRAkyvuetES2uhkj8bWpxYl/XGuIc8HQZSItEPJQr7MNkG4UWmbVd@yLelopNRKbrNGo8Bl@iIg6PS25Fcs3DUFPPh1GAlLgfCB6Zd1ri3j9FGjkFmNx/DTgWUnwLSDrTlqzm7VU3tTleICs8gYcuKd8Hckli0w5iv7SJhIhtBJqcUXT4nqpULaeUyf72uJwyI6PQJAfnIaM8VyyjSrT4nEfMw7oheFi17nMnjmeZ7UGtHq1O7D4SrCgsS4LwghIPmXCyVWwYhDdsD5DPcPCmC9Z5guBBSXInxoa6ElhzsghFmeXSEwipY5UZG/fooPMNnVGbCDjimFO3yu/Twvy8bEDyD4WK6DDOgcJDbE8BUXHqST7nbfF@V/04R2D1Pk1nVc5l8PxuM5p2WcOzSIFpmZa1XKoZwaxh2eDmzG7lten10LQAAceVl@FnTdsdem1JABNpohpenKgYXqhYUNxGqkj@tCI/ZKUF5emLCTbMrsTu0dzmmhmyutbQiqlIgXutlrWqqBABFxt5n@XBANZiTVPV7Oq5tceHOCBZhHkJ@8TzbN@fVUTW6A7NFJjiCW@//mbHaD/zdLpQ3uF45mBoQmaApaU0l1ZWCIqWui1vGD5sPtkYBlEGDLdBrJtuJAlYxAYloOmqX1FAX1jiBMVosSBN/EFuugaNuOY83lG/7s8kWVTdTbI7faqsNdWefGkaFIJuosdIgLXuSyTIpGQ5YVgTvnETqjjjgL3dqT8pViMmJmXe38ynvA3qMO3FqI1wt@6uilCpnNGSzOhQ2q0LHNNkbvG2aTjKKOzXqAW55eEneeeZpYV0ErEJHMTjcuzzzPoWj1o7v3vqmDz9jV1QZ/buMKzJ95IaVHfvsNtVBGGa1JwB/y9KogldioFhtVUswb0uiMnCujAKGKNRQpXsCoholnXyDwwWjNUhfofzmXBegWQONV2IpHOrJiwHo1Wx8f@KcUvlZbHnqptTo9lIw8pvkpW4WNzlGGxbvaWUoXmyhoaA0XvhIwrhfmy5Q43ggYzpRTHPMd5ovOlJTenPjZI7cnAcOemNSw@x8OfnFg1zi2aDVGX287A8rBCD1ZJTX/N3TwtXKdMr9C6CmsZJTvQEcV2XAlMy6WA0x7jWtQVbHUHmcbXgOJK2xCfqM4qYrWdC/yt1CD60Bnm7@WN2pulWN1BPimD9sCApnxli7Aw6oijmrfw6oXlmfRaTtizpYiO24Ol7ou1wB9PDI8P3sbZnjVwPHZM73UE6rlABf5eztNhWlqGrdAoe9i8Rgz5iyfmBWoMes4gX@ylDHitLPWJ20XRL753FXKBkNK0W4SUrwE5tia@K0X7Wco9u62AaP@XiwtnQ8Y1rewySSUmdVbnDvoGOCO4PGeP0kWKqab4GOKKhHEu58KY@d9foPVYRVq/9RjNSKMGBQ8jlIpgGLtcy/5FUsuuT61zN6F0A2zhtkyECvdsYEJ7Re8bRcr0tPaBMbR0@u4iqjuYmBNzaV/jsPXKxG3Ea/oZd0cqLbKxKaYAcNYB97wEod6IzuGdsMamGm1rhYkBvXbzdm1mUaiNQAEfYe/5GRieoeFmjJ49GS2U6kIHzT5aT7L@yK/STmcBO/T5UDlUvEVZWlDRPZN@aztNvJOHK8@q2XQ6LXSY0FTOgmVdZyoTxH1l8fdCwuQyT3keFqfv3JBxeRpElvDaxpUiSF/Vt6fApVLKtmxzPMP3HaVpy3EGH1JSIFQ7FmpjoFzSGt51JXZD3RG7U9h89MLDMY9Wd9W4BW9tRPcS6IP95nWFHp5rulNpKjibOsSZrkXr@hGc0MzVbangdm4cFuKregerdUkxIKKpRbWwttZxDdVpmQODf6b57Dp4JTWzFt6i0BCzwDhrzOeK53P8kWtCaTQDYlkd6Kj0zaFJ1jWKvtF5NfH8z8pAUwd/q7ynptlOTffN9qoAIwvkgo3vhcnpkLI0dmzoYo1xASF2VQa4RFW4rpLA/nTiUiIfDI2eyc@oWCcp52MWuEyH9@zmxuWjF2W@NKcN0eYjzKtZAirVmTnz/O9SgE9mbSjXyfD2Ebdrlb@Nw6B3qO2r1sbebGLtvtO3@2afL0gPbKsqB/DjmJ8psg51wLrXxzVyo9HC2vkwPQfOYHAXeqJo5ILScbpLcdrHXbW4JeyD4M6MFniIz63jd8aYyw40rKw1fXMC7ZLnjJ2RqZBtVdABjvXw9yoZ6s9@/6KDSGu7@kAR//uLwr@1b9kznPFoRJ/maDDx6EVRFdoMfZve1OVrXmi1peP21DfOsKUKR1UsiKFJ9@UipmWN233chM452@w5rXbfug3plmmMbess5Y/6cOud@q5IGYspD9FZHVhAXnemIr9Uw/7H@DlYVehiAIk3a4Fhjb6ybJCO9nsrI@Os7fEBUTSxMo4Jh2oj3xVepu305dcTazwHGlokFYzw8pkJNKzCXSzLWKlZ0eaLuRgWyzVWcikp6aiQK2YaFB5t5fjSwgK6UBXLZPhrFULhXBJGoQUvH0JusaiIBgit0NAtuC/w18JqqKWNnN2f9LybApOP2HdARcPX6mELWiQdGrWGNsuwxWcVmfVBCndPwrcJOtfEXDutkls7r0LhtIFiOBZ8mvCBopusHEMbWCOPv5nSXTkbJxZJQV/8@pQhp81seWdaFEzH7PJZEDTdpiIOHZqnBR1EaeOcPg6iozDnihcXXLbTA6GuDNg8sB92ldqydP3R8uIP2kzl86dmz8BF3I@tMa4CXcIVxLLL1i3dCvtrE8OzvjaBnK1iNjwKgs9EuuEzA9C2BN4To2e1P1koiABJQWCxhJR/FtgfnW6WxUXf8nANVWBYMzCFLMeZGLmuCf2GJSGvD90Hp2DMKxDfX7k09LLhdWc0w21oMzKtG1m3xjTKKr6ruo6rVpetReJiMhxNPPFZjgOt0gqPQg/PyN27sAC48hpEK@sbg/HykerQkCtoYaJRnBtXaePfsAZOj32jmGagtIEShsr5EsZ5AM3zM1wa5NpLOJHSvuPMJw50KC7P2GsoWzPDFMu2xutHc8ZjXCbkfzEzvOXArQ@px/hW738oBOVkOUUe367rz/c839K@A@cdOxO3baIxOMgk3C0QqZp7/rJm3Cri4EEsF@Fe2trZG2gOHXsyVtyJvbZVyK9tFcpsWsyH2IDFvrb/5Hk8zA20DPw2LdSEzt/EG8zmppVrBq4xmWWDIrZaji6G9vsSD/m5S0e0BvmWOLt4OFSbxPVDZ1l/59nMNcd37jCB8J8MH5ptnDm8Ne2nzhPHdqA1GoGgHB6Z/DCBhbUeyyNitMe4XR7o07k1mWMCu6IR4tqGMTJbUL6DuekubREH/NAYGyuaIhobpP5fYLqVV6xBy3Rf0aBfyLyqS7uI0CfmlPoWqxmG10Fl3G5zlRjH4xbqyMKMjTdyHJu/Sdqm4aM9WS9VoCmg193nylVc4b8wLrC0f7aY1cNzvlDE7PDTLlbl1TVbzoC/1yxLsi2@LMBwLdNLPcbDE8gtn2UKaF/eWhlSWCtD5l0j0GTPDY/m6Zd3NeYgtekHrALqG27bwZkwYVizQCd04sEtYjrYNMDXDrSA8FOQWEZ7Is5evA2twbA1pNfKDkOoNI/MFm43atExIWNjerMw@ciQOCMhtKgrOFnAF1dYqfMs9gx6I/Hbm62FftQiVa0RvUhSr5wup/U6im2Z7TcGjpo5RK/52PSCP@Q59ZSMK8aqQ9WIRpFTBm2hX1qTFlevgUIzMJVx34U@f2q8bnjbP79lyXzIZGjiJPPiLMxK1dXx@pRZZ/l8eiBcXVMRZweCLAnOEeT6obK7UvNE8PB/@OCrKWiEm/msf6YJiK7bZ/AB@Ylri89dOPCZ44271vQQ8MZ9B6vECWYrB1Hgw2sGmrZWZQJKz54M@OhDL7T0atih7phC59cqyoDE9dhUTPtcoRPmpjdz5PDdZKldPAx1bHYUccACzjQoj/2NZUEw8V0ygRqWjbjeU0txwk7zWbECdBlxL3zJAPqWM1ZGHn1TI@/ZwePDE3XkaUvbp90@7se4occtnNigF9OhIalXhhua7@Qr0jqWN049ONaUvccHKgZYQW8@o6HAB2fmFj4rxz3F0aNGyljZC0Jfc7xcQfzk5MnjxHzvJ4vt9V1naMbD3nvHx0nc2/LV46Xe4diPoHZ0nenK6Af7mhZfwr7PbZodXCU9l6S0CtKJCb1RYMZP@IEvtypXbWdkdk5mI/MzaDxRgnt3TD6/MpNPjXOrh7WQlVYSiioqK6n5bDy0OBs626YbfFeV55k1QmnZpk@Kf1YuR0HNIZNyM8u1h3Uz/te1GJYWKxE@LJKWvsmtY0uBmtHroylleH9fxDRNW0XnY6ML5cpyKwtrMcCy@eGBc36HqWRTdF6UwEkZA1cp1q1LyQvKEER3Cl84PC8cwdhauQxmHYDAOb@0wl@Y9sywFZrLWqdelCE2LmpbG@Qb5h0mpIIVPud4IPTSOb5gVT2LtckYvyXhEzcUZW/vwcFtEY4ELdeH@vjpc/bM8PB0k/UBwxibd8B4rhm9UnDcCo/WWzmd2nEBlL4WXm@0vD6X2bHhdhx7Nr19Eo42t2LTTocVB7DQRoHMgTW1lrVVbT6u9Wz5MqPb0ub7OJzZgh4cPvVGAHr/nX@maek0nWmEXy3NrbeUjF/BWQxNxgwPygt7nRwEoqGNeosKDvGlvdHH5hSXo/DR4GWd@qXtW35N21eIr25O1vkV1/hl16R3ww8dWUZNa2sA5tb4sZwaeD92Bhd9R90zXNO7Y5mEUFuXpdKaLJVCcvpNMY3DoTTFKMw3WZLvojqa2OFzfb2kOJmBb37k29E81T98ORazE4l4fPF8//DmO77tDE9/4zvGIOzbt2xDbAwDj2CvnNiOhodEgZZq4iZOiUDgLsGYXa1quRLbwVP2y9AGxSlFdKKjePy06mzzUuzyKpe1K9zpJpdlJnbhBSdr8tMhAS6eawd5YsqZxjbH4LPp7xFjdL45e8tIr4WGVMulwaamwpt2K2LzHKC0efns4Nn@8cnuyfPjerpxJcfFFlGOm21Dav7m4Y8yHRnyLsgG9YWfFUubTAeQHJ29jvqw5@eLQc6uZa26kLV5puQdjLN5adupFO2VTClXgJ8i89TIFxo/dOKw/RxT@YitrmW@xXBAJJU3OWiZ0oQyK7P0soRHhudBtoT/9dsfyJdlMujLExbHe0KN6DlOR6Tomez2x0/x0e7B4@dH@8xHcM40F1Zn3K@Wcvz0V2xTFBPKqWvRsosqi4ooUSirajX6KAqEiapRVqYdqnTyKvA5BPOpg3tbRewtFtsk@EDBaFAoqf/8zdRVVMUVhHEIG/WRijJBeQzATnDX2Z/9pMNPJvfPmvCvOHGHJEBpT78kdpSu2E@KFKWKOVp90QmdBE5bR4MjyOeXx0h0MD1w5QUdE3XtCKE4nerBb60RJzz5CRGD@KcZ41AUntYE/ehzC/eNchy6eHjSIivj7DUdGKayXbzFBXieGXQ6PqA@scf8gBJxnEEE@EgNBEqSbRKy/Cx9ORQwur0BrNwye5bNPBv0e3NcZq@Az3C4p8w3LytKLXojig@aX9@j9MfDQSjgjdOWvNTpOPX@176b6lUYmKfpB2D7FWHrgvlXufmLFJb1zROZ5umHkcBT1ATWPPGA5kjv0IU1Nt8kPicWHhzlS0pmDaFozonSGJynwN8KCNg5nFj9MygoYDEoJbE5nKdnuo0YHuNWTqWQjbB9UGlBrDnlq1OuHeeWz@WzWgqQVM59gHT@cg933nGA8XgZGF86t0bVly1gr@1tJqO6aFbzFV6aqU37i4z8MkB0E8JKF31Ers4gDkSZxwC/mogGzUlCi2NUlEdRLYqiqONAO0P@2B6h3RaEkFkMiMVpZOKBvlO8uWjszvxjCVt4G1DobP5NAUjRoJUhU1yWxH7mp84YWGZhJzffz4yrs3ibhud9efxmLjoNEHlQvVmb5tvw/EsARP1Ssd5zUJn09eYxXLbyCwRxjCDK8jKWrX/BTsendiPFeZMBm/5IsGyYmW0w/5NUbwXP8nzv3jwLLnb9JDckFrt/bDuoFz@CzLCYntIzKS0fn2cpm12aJZEjkQxkB0@oeAvJgWgCMdE2rVfOyNvd2z/46uGz4xvnnVHI6PVgIMlr24lTRU3WG4EhGs7WYpE8eJQ6fvLgkV8Qc6TzIQkM2ovIibYuJ/PuLoKcL5@@nrVlGF7P3WqMX/A9ltfxzejrUKNIN/DQ0h@QLi1hVB7RRoTrievFZdTK5dahNIeXCoHe47vIbqAai19e1RvbtVM7Er3JCUsqwhcRdQsrAZhOva3NFDL7zcxhxoIb9E7w7h8vXBczy@uivJnBY3dwH@vYOZsfOCQcQh6h/PrJgIiU1JQfdGXtO@Ra9/xYLJ3f8McP6AkfSxJCOJ9eR/EQqBP/skCUIvND/cR5dn3odA6sluQfB8PPtfOP3wqOtONHucTikjganiccE9cHTstTldYrxOIo7QhWkq07Is@HF5egQqO@9mwCnd9nzogfFUzzUg9N33TkgPh9OOET3Cb76mQI4br0OTJpjBAktwKRgZLRAFWuP4GUECfkTRN4BiGkV8dz8kTG1WEnF5vG1b457Vg9kO2xeBIk2kea1mDBKXqYaTo1z47KVGbzUlhbFT/GvYFhsn/QUYrTOQJG3VAtu2NOY9GLaLzcgPTRPXrx4jwal5fxEh3pKM447Fw/2zFAv6CtlyTGWNRO/@DEZdKiVLopJcDtOmB@KJF/T0mppPY9ia6bqqIufjx2H4MR1IhYd2iMWGxi84ObVEbW2GnMTtJJN0qNn/1ms0SCukjwIQ@VUcwumXj7HTPsGYulqsAE6OrZHfy8sUasrqlqA8yUSJxt4v1Be6Bx4SEocQl6tRClTGCryELQcQCMeCVROYNDHPSX8Gwal46/WuJN16nQUIqDNKFcs9o9FroGalFzlEulsijQRalYYsB9N8WhmgKwN@Scr8sDdcUhC0Az6NCqUmQuyG9KvAilG@GIfCJOZwB0IqHzGv1DGxjAmp@m2O67@Ivt21BX8JyZ8vOTR81iPCWz4JSHnmt1cKiPHzkcdNrEJRFQTVMLQaMV3kf7GKPh8V1NfowEni71iCqMfE2kRsJkuH4p6pw3NW0t14uIohQgZBYbALEVpumDw3Pq/EnXJX7Lhf3Pf47XrsqxzZ18pjk4T0Rz6Qq8tEqO5dhHm6eKslnXc@nq/c2GYYxPZWakslsPz81@t3XQS53KMsuwbCq1pedfn420/NYXdfX1tCHXi9XkWePZGXv27PN3zXdxeXo@k09jrBBhe4dvZQ0yECkXWInhb@lD9yEufdb00uUowD09xetU5YKcStWjDfgnr5fw8ED1mlpTdxrv3sXrBcjTdHYawVsK2eF98qZ@Eo006Xr82LKsFDsdeZ0O/Jw@a/B7diP8SSRiChMOSp27seG0S27TXbPXm@wbM@5uRSb4eTQWcZ9848WLF2h4QQ97cyTic@jMT6PcNHIRpqf1P/vpxlXy8llz@8@@NUyZG/g5xM93r56g@VjLfbSx8dGDB9lsEqjEzc@@8ezru7u72YfJ3LN6bierpDe2//RPNjZ0fVtPbTQ8T2tE62dnn8t6Oiurf/bjaPPZs695Xi3zf3zzXU3DVwFe51hM@GSYBkZ8F@GnoY51xt7Ac9Zl@E/mN52Q2UBzq/uGRd5EgMsjM/prRuZltsG02k7hv3z/8HVkHKnpqRcufMeR15F8McKNYABbxredR2qRbQyWv4rMUtVqFYyF//JvIX7tqwAHfWbb8KrlfFj5WaSmVCnK20gtDwZN1yHd/@ub3wwxDxcTVVLj/Oc@q8MjZwu6vNOAZ4uebQnP1lLSqdQ1/tOK97R7jNnj/th08GPxjw0fZlRs6HUf1ROJRENV4FGbFCmlafopDdiEWYvGWyKBc4VxFxZym/OJcAG/FxHiKWAq4ituFg7EatzhxfVwL5Y8lRf/0M@RFMlv3Dcf1mogCjO1zFYtQc/GabnMyZ9ihaLsOPflLSiyNL0eM/iAwKzJjKWLupxMJu83QavUkabKVNAvEj2Vo5HIyzlJfcpG2NzGwk4RQUoW1MFfINw@Pn/@v/75D/78@/T3A/r9BzyGzO5Y3dQWwxu32XmNP6xWk2uufHlKlvssXS6Wi6kmuzqNbdVrjSOmpT9@G81loscMWwkKdRr3RzgjwVOr4ctHA221CHepcdPcTfjUAguFmEdZHo4JycSYSASaYLFaS6mfg4yt@TmCZxp6SOTeh0KS9UJJbtT0nH5Yk9OaTMVWYv1NjzlCHkR24NmAP/qHZwcHj4ULvjfIkftQ0CXPRoDK7c9C7ZUi9XqqYTZAkWU1H8j9jfJGsZwv61AoqwFXVoGOnIcSuK8W1KKqg/h4V99gR5zXGyzhP6eJW5/nqtoURjI4@FMUZxqRIv8AT01ikUt4Gu@26u@AdUXSdVFPE9tKo5YQGMFHbd5vJJSrq7r6RaJSEf/btcBYoYebICONK0XZ/gJg1W9C5UDprTa/2Aawie36dtXZo5/aRBIr0awTzTv3G1/U6tuLIASU@/cTKGrvA5zaJjBpPJHYVJSN@so8AOBGDJSAbSjAq@2r2lV9@@pqexv@t@l9Jb7gerV9458@82dFmLk/VZvTeqp2mjoVbNMAu5qqoYuaOgVDDb4QDpohKQKKyVSKbLGtyIhphQyYmFnWtvRMKjf9KL8PqlG9oWAPpqrUtXyuoXBJ9VJlZYWfXa4V83EVRVHT6TZxu6HKXkqRl@@//J/xd/r@y9/Hdh6qZUmKpLawe1DivQR4PbHZkydP8PfEtuEffk/4Y6MLOjxBN5u/bB7CDxM4cxesDiAUmKwX83Izoc10FtmW8wUUC79044lGo//opV4qRHkPGrflvfTA8ZeWPf/ol1Y9UuRtCet522M8T1KE6j2UBdSfmqLUtoe4GgtHphXsBHxW/Vx5vqtgr9UY01xDm/fIqgf71VKp5nmoLkqRS4TSeo1/j9/g3@sx/p208e/oNf6xkzf4dzTGP/akhX/PPPw7eY1/uy38Oxni34PX@PdkjH/Pe/gnRaqgo2/upAfpdlo7087AYLG0y9L9dF/rYAcibbL0LD1j6aGjdcBkwl8aTFa6y9I9lrbTtqaBJxjGLD1GUxc@PfjrAhQX/iyczz/T0m0GqQwAKL@1iL5vQf7FT6U69DzllyZo06qmptW81cCz3utyQy8VmYoFozbrL0@jDTxEVC9lWWtmbpy@ZBEPNPFKJHV6muJjCkzPVvBY@KurZnP/6cNmM4US7PSJczj/Pzwchq1r/4eHzpNDZ@jA/@Hh4RNm1hL3E8p9eKq1xLb47ERqlZ3TsoLV3ZcwkdT2zmkto6A5nwBpoaNb4gOfOUT41jZOpSgDBeeiQmpU5eK8clEhQ2AFQ7MSBBDBuAEcK0L9ApeKr4ddwHN@QY74QuPFi9PAxA2pFxen2J2AfmLwD3pq2Ppf4d/6f9f/k@csVm@AWhS7vNqO0RPHv3j88urySrxr8VhMWGLb8IcOYMcol1c1NFKgSzDVY/FG/OqKu8E7Ft/mAGuYxnaNIs8DQu2PBGlSuvwV@6/7xbTFc4rHjRvzCf7T02k6Ha@0/OONcXLLeEvzrPEKXVaz2aprjT/9MR1ivROnQLlspaJtMW7Rs3qlkvVthWKlUvQtm7FY6eZTS@9oedCLstl4vFIBy44PNg3WAGwRwPqWHEA1PaNN9b4SuTw4pOOdQUzkInHMERcMsTSdAo8XikTlsnzvXkxcVLqzG793Ty@l374NXEYjcNIWnJrNjuU2m@ieeftWbso04V7KgT1dfPsWZFk07rixp3gPDSQUUzT2kV6jNEuOC4QogDfTUvoci77hGeOxG3tjjZIyrkzy5DhdE5FOO@5p9Gff@9a3TqPVqqzI5JrVEACmwnLb2/lsrZbPgjlfBErJm5f8xpReoqTFrzZTMqcGkzejEeGlFQtxLhuj6A8NI9upQQX38GGXVxEqdpbNxWMgXeOgn11F8I87a6USd2fZfKyYKIm/6kac1UB14H/Yrc0ksluFrfsNRn/TZQ@K5MqlWdWuqpdmGUcHryptcQkgbmU0793LlICmxXTlVGo2H@6e7DabVVmWsT2EFzqScJfw7qGRG61TgedKjTrmr3EajZYr94k5tGKORaIVEU6JQivBiiUig2R1cZ8y5F3SxJjBhqTTF1@SGELaAMcItujz37PHu3v7J0l9GzQh/dHuXlI/fv4goqE1N7eTdwbtR/u7Dw@fQ4Rnj/d3j/c/Pvhs//kzcPfYxfzxJbB4z79h0xL7BXshvXLfGKZpmBPTbF5MJhev2SvLalpA2MHEsiyn5zLPbJqmOYJg/lOBX9vyjFevDHdED3v/o@@8/9F/8/53vvf@d77z/nd@8LMvf/Ad@P0Eft/j3@/9m1IO3z/78p/97vvf/h1w/A/w@yP4/fRnX/7mN/mP7H8Mv/8Ucvtj8QuF4z8JYP3Kz778/o9/9uWv/hB@/1L8fnjz92s/Xf77wbdX/zDe9393fZjv/Vv4/R6H5Yf93m9zN/zeCP/bPNyv/vD9b/w7/v@n4g@Nv/P@N/4YX8LyT3/4p//p/bf@va4X//Rfv//2999/@1vvv/3d99/@x/r73/zXWjr8@t33P/iDv/rD3/urP/wf6P8n9P69u/y//@E//Yv/5S/@t7/4Q/H7Kfz@HZh@@hf/Hhj2b//gR/j//T/42z/6Ef7/T//qb//g1//2V/5HMvwWN/zf//Lf8Pdf/9p//Jt/8d2/@uk3/@bXf/o3v/UHf/W//@r/@Zv/8a//29//6//@W@j4Wz/9qz/6lb/81nf@8tv//C@/9eWK93fWvr@8g/uX/wAud8fzLnDukq8PdfnyF8Ln70ONeSrAJ8Dd/@T9b/4yMPhvMPb@Oz/BBbnwW/H/E12jMD/htv8PGPSbeUafNJjg9@vvv/M9JNF/BySC/4Be3w0sCz7c8t25Bcj6L65FipjlxcazqBcTW9DD2CqVRAMaeG9TzJ99@c9/HCTxy4tQF/wgxe@ipFrw@y7KuPc/@ub7H//j9z/6rfc/@hVszZRsKbmbVLT1SxWhCVRydwiHAfN3CQcBP8fWdJqgEVYl8fnn4Pi58Pz888@l6dsUrgC//xZcPycn/jDuBX5MePl@wh0XuIbDcGPaN26i89tw0kiGBCabIFVgy9dTchk2TQiMpmzKxCgkBppu8QFJfJMrek8lfM3/58apxBIYRoxeJuZGMoh4IglulHKQTGI69elFihPjysoWd6HJJ0o3W2KYg@k0MYUeKRgghQR4PUiwarWawIhVjg9YOWq1IiNUEokq5Btj8zjJZhFBTB8QFIhZTRyx5lZ1yiMmEF7NJ0dCQqcjWdPlRLH6EBKsTh8yhIXACezLl9VasTqtIbh3nB6JaeIB4YTAqolp7R3YqwQzgWNRD98BKsVqIlErYoKYSV48ySYvpBxljvKeYAlRBvClgd37jH0ka0WZT4RsIMF4aHwn5qF3aGpuB/xPE1siO/TvG@m3RQTfoKREKoz775CquMO1RwwAcBVFVVUGP5zu22H3wXvKQSUoWfgkOIQEcQRxQOAAbIhlkaDyTZAF0o9Utz74SdQknpvNzU0pUpMz8iFNDCWg1@6elfmtJ29516jM5HxJRmeTFozz3Jmbz2jYYevhFrw1@N/foHXcCVYhtDajOCYYZTw99lGC/@7f32IfQe7pO3eTmJLIOFkck8eMbicSsg6p1pyE9AVINwnYlwC9ldRplaajElIyyZhajaAfOzw8FKiRwxdVKQHcr2c0tOP8wWQyiUAMVU2qyaT4qvQlB1UYVPIVX3UTaU5jmEzXsxXo31QYOrFwd0SDfis6vnv3DgqL1nKUD6BHycSyDj1bJE9w4BtjB4OZv91Az5Yk3p1mWp7fSx6jawvjLC6xGNuKS3zVL0fCf2JRvViMoikOZaLGtvxVPnlN8ocWIzVE1H94H6@Yi/uee4ds7/DJk/2nJ6NGg0km3SdpNkeu0zY9b51gjmG83acP@aYAvZRHNCL1OqZ8UtZRLEn75TQJzYOHRwfHZcZpIkooFkCKV2jYWJCipEmR0ejFdkSshJDxghNHPsZ3eZ7/mF7KYIK1ihRpm9gtAYbDf1aRnni9B84U@vJJWU5qeeyixWnglUlfd8rl6jstW5DgS/YJw6O4@L5dqJ24dFzd3iaiSbVLhQbL0QgFnJdqNbGkiGlS7Xj/BCKcHDJNT6sMevqX2YKezWVzeiafzxV0LZsvZfO5Ygbamnw6p@taKZstFUuFK6n2OZuqiKsC5kF1YNq9cX8TF/LIp2k5RI/NejqJf3omA2@AmNRyhcbGxuBSQQRPiS0ucUXWFVgvFaTAV@Bh0lck9hVwggfSwGVWTKxxOzisiIVGeEJGjK82krUcVO64dAqMxMFJo/BTGUH1gc5@6CdFNr7xjTGr1aCTrRw8kiIgpfrMX2yjWB21rxIfdSauSb49xjrWZxZee6N2LG80MGZQN9OqFLm6uuoCpINHTK/pZOUxOvi@apNLC8xXU0P6/59f5IkoSk3aHtWAGbdTIzAaYMxupwwwtsCY2061wGiBsbSdssA4qWW09HZqAm2EtM3PlmK4dbUqj80pHmXH3eSaZw66Ku4pqMqUgC5vi7MaayJeDTdnOEanivsbcVF9LH4pdaodp033bEkdteV0Zqo3ng1w8f3AcatRUMWivoeFV5firq9qnTXUkTOCBlPPFRJ1LQ3yGX9aMaknO2p7YBruTq6cK6IlmDnZyaXLF5bdcS7Uz588/mQ8Hh2ZtL5/J1sqd1Q8QAK3eu8Uy7lco16X5USdkmngtX28ciobG8DQptFR4Nt17LGn6MUGRO5YbrUaje5kNK2cSRelqyDzEpANc1STMF4Cc5JE0l0K3i/bjg31rJw0ktYl5brc7Xavti4Tc4tkXCrcBvS4Uoxk6zKwVpRQuDKbJBVr7gkuRheamUsxaVSW9VxRrtQrc3shL1caV9L9odmxDFzTf5q@vBkrD/KIQ41AQqdMuiq7jjMut8yu45rzgBkt7wfkCN0MkJWvguRO05ji5c3k8hgIaMgpB3zKz/Gq0Tq2OojQxj60jPXGtn/CF/Knrit6RsloipbB/1sMOv7fPbwO/zq@IVZGl05wl@tTkKTQVNjsMR4oPnbYiePQ3XEPzPaKEHt9gxbs7bmO5/09wjww7DPu9dDiR0sFXp8YeGmEN7TG/RUhno@GuBnTdP/BIOwPW4AgVWsK8ABe7sBxlgUosOfPVuTySXCYIxCDn@YIwY8OPv7kJPQ92d/d@0TKsweHTx9e@@REoBx7vP/oJLAWuK8fNReA@Pr@48fXreITQaUCB4c3WK7gGzQJV/zegy7VPWHM5efGNBpf8M1olhesQOW7DsvSib9DzWAoLFoma/P9sdjHo/NEhKqnFUqSNGK2c8EKadZxBgMD783sboBj38CdNyYqLwO63hWTvnDcQefC6pgb0hPc5FPS8HJAREL6BIAMJ23avG@NJTydqoM3WuJkRGswMdkEb41d4QgfdEKja/X60BRcOH4AqWUYDH4f@kB8M/yM1zuMeRrkdsNncDO4FJGMsREpVu7d0565wNW1dLncM8/Ktf0pMBV7DkxuuDk5o7blR0xtRowt0AJ7Vt1rjKC4MtmtvIb6DCigoHaxZPGIoQ6G@nFdBx3sNJ0yso5decM2U86o5kXTV@YVtCuFxE4WGo5xt12B5ipXhmKAXnRRdmXpr//FT5CRt1IgsyKaLOMC5A1NUknz1UvFXLGU0YvJYqmYzWn5XC6p6UnoWBRKkG5aK2r5Yq6kJYvZUiYLqiT45koFKcJXd6W2CCR8ywDWbuOldtukPKv9mhThU1TsTcyIs4gR2CdMNiGOjNeYe2Pa4bhlVWU9y7Q0g34TQDRYm0UePdpLP3okyw/QghPze2lZ7qAlV0ynCw9k2SSfvSIqALLD4xTxbBB5zC3p9IM9WZ5wAHispiz30bKfx2EXWbbQsrf76BGm00WLjvEh2Bn34ZaBbylAMBstmQyN28jy6wAchNvlCWUJ0320YJro84j77IGfLH/s45NOA4QjHo5D@MTP6@6uLB9wy@4u@uxRxnMc1U/RskuPLLtggUoiyz0w9FyonrLcAiNWFVlug6k9M8ANrxDEsxftsSHLM04gJJEsTym00T6T5abvjsl88sknRn/cMXv8mbn82wbUwMeaTvYftT7@uNXrtdzZ7v7HR@izt/eJ0Z1N3FavJaK1mvA4EAd8zoaz6w/geNBsGoOlPp@Cj33Npzlrmohb03gNOImnh4kMm3vgswc@y2b3ODR4hhC0hc@DIXwfGC3y8R/yoe@01ZIryKiog9I9wFBn6Ere5NBou04F7dPqBmPRWDQ5q@fTjQp5sCFom@nKFV0AHMO3gf38@OWsPq2mG9VptaDzZSHdmHw61XOWnNwY7milXHnD2NH0bGJaxn3OTjfKooq2w2Lava03LPY0vqNnsmX5dGdHketaY0fXiuV84YutiSzHy/jeyRTKEDAdhV4wvuL1QmOnkAtFKRQSRkovFwrxyhWQYwxNaQvlSzMWuzCNs3gc0cXeGmSBXz88o3xalW5smpxWOV5sFq9Mq1qFHwvG0jdgdfAMykl77LgcYg/ATXfSZbrgWNZKRRnST6Vi8ThIJhIi8J2vFXvxtZOzk5PPQWZBP1j0Ip/xWzMrwvrxJ3sqdCyFDc@OVB@hru@46h4KlgUffrSh73QCKrH6CbSH0B3w3XDviesM1P0p9O2xw@B7@CeCqeIcJ/XkkwU4x9CF5inj1t0KHTxht02GR2taHWZUa2AyOixGWDEjfkEtcbNWqzarQ35HcS2I9SmjcyfnYA48jnuwoZiiX@J@DOHRrKavKq3qNDIFOM0qU7SXQ6fzUk@0Kx08UfNB9QFGrjTh26qYVRNvapYjcqW7Y1cZm9ie0TWfmS5ujz843AS9ADdpxLrMjG@yU7rXeQ8V5yul5jJ7jtnTyTBmKLVWfNEpZEXSxL7mZ/mSdg3hfPlVpVtlsS/ilddgdTdZrKM@iO9kK53YA9aMg0v6Zfdll@ksn63QVXcxhASViGhD9yXHq7VPQZXhgM/KZUBElPEZwMSUAKzVIQ8jPrKuKu3qgMUUNmVxIk@20qvWMfZbfG0rstxQlPrbhlRTlBdSDeppZRYxqt6kRccws3RL09P5yhTctEK20oeCNb6YVtzqaOKalQFYxZAK3xxlVICcQDUA8@Zt7P0vfzO@reSq3K1CoN4OQHtoqs3qtGLjwS7AEtVMFTwS9Ww6Cd1JeBWS0CDroArkk5lkNqkU0BVa42QuCY4aaASxQUxmTE6mp2lVS2qmloTa/9LqvGTx5FkMtA8iGVjGzj5eEw0uUEjIlWSFr8HiCX1rwKAUHGZsK8SmICkqmDGgeZ@NrGQfQR2ZxoBixOMKy2zFBpsxDLN5Mhnt1xvl8v509DXwiimvd/KJQjrxJh6vxDbiVc98LdUqUg2lCuV6tAE8K0abmDcZ1qGMx5taQS/X6y3MYSGdzKQzkD2r@ba3LdfkRjK9kdeghK4Y6TGMCwyuy8y1kblbE9VnvHOdaSW9Iqm0sIJS1GJ6adWumriES/oEQGkkhB1SmMVOZX97YCwaLejRaDxawXHpDVkMJ4KE49e3g6iN3tN2ZNCf5LJc0jHAXFDSDrB0WIW6krB7zrIlKXIpXV1ebUP/MkUr7EBDZBtkUtTafSlSZgz0uFNxxkhqg7EPXbiX2K59wb@nuCIY4Ep0MBuojbScxrSwU8Q@w92uOywKiBnusK7rmUZdL0D7BjLTD6rrWgVH3SO45litAeW9S8BvO1HDjSKfstnMSCg@Ze8x1ktsSpTpyHWy71Z3e0e7Fd@2hwN/p5Isy5WoHLmMRqJX8CdF7tPuFJ3vTmGR0P4UvqK1bQJ93kVIYrC9S3/kp4zXg8SMMpcP9Ub83VNrcFnMKLyDDwLr6iqymaISEYv8K5@@1HNQRrbjr/qHjg4OpEDTlcvhqGUk9XLkfUMvZp4cHNoP3Ucm44v@i9mmXIuwtKbgGvpKWbjm@KJfuVTUZf0sGWH3I5UIO1OiWpk2BrDRcemLwhfFL548P3x@@EiKnG683XBwRJv5ZGHv7K9@DQJGM9koY6fVyLSarYgVVLWaom3reHpPgZVB2He1vJJ@W@PsWyOPvA4@73/5h9npdhHsOmivZSjCXEKv1bQtncUjo/df/j4e23C5/9nuYxb1jBn7uz/5sV74uz/5V7QuKXpV8Wj4tBCBkGjU8oXI5eXo8vIKHu6XizQiHKlsIQ5mPlSvReZ7D8opw9gqJLL6fbuSEmG1ghaPeEpETEgUchHvrfDS00Xw8mcMyEnOYxFE9o@snK7d30am0IItS2w@MW16JeCK4pOXbxkDS7vW6fUsnUypFCu/U9j2O2WbvcMR93fKBntZreEssYYbnfwx5q1arYZQWLSWSG1FmZ4Dv/pVpZFgNEoNvb4vzC1763SRo083WKlkg7vpbYk5jdMtDzp7Wzb9mVueB1bfZm698piMsy6pVKdD59lsmyxXg/LfSgE6p/H3v/ybup7/uz/5tbfNt83Pdei5lUp5TY/8XPv5zyHAmh32freLRuBxKzwagu4aW3FfNHRQpQheIt5lPLzfecPuGuoMVs@GjjnapHPUc6homvzYpk6Mgm3hBtwkac10qEq8IkmBdklasdtrJwkG28Kz/KFuSpfSV9ALGlNWBXEpfWUOChyG0Hw67aY3mLgjWtAfo3haI8nuQRRI4St4ItYGbRwWMlcBMZXauhmVo@wR1UgnYkPT8/B8LWhFpK9AFHHuGl5RbOAedwxp2SDkVQxCeJJHpw5pNyDtAY/QJNcY5Z4HSDKOHY9kg@YsfQWUAaKCBToCs7YhQAUEy1eAAJCHmABsNdg2y8TZpZVIVOaHd13hKmc858zw99dKGA2hdXA/tx@5guHACTR2vOkH@UKUMKhnIUcfCIfBZ2GroPNjdLKh0kUb4O8MCmDRYTMxyhq7d2@OVbVqdeKMcoTwz6wRDj9ROdjLcQVgfn/po05ZTjI8Fq3iuwZsBxRPELrAdQo/D60SispktF5JEvzfmWmRI68VFXlUMAOivHitaAPJIDKSnZdhm21XmaYX4ixAvg24twkpOoor6ASeTj9S9c99zyvA8OcR/xxtkD4n4SE9wbfXN1gzaPYmeIgxHrPDhYHYGM0P0kEpdjD2YwexICvWgEJ3LRc6KDQL7J/KFctocYw2P8WM8KB1y3qW4QLiXBw/FAtDM/gaeP6USGeDztBoO1Cg3six6cAqOlwD12YDR4CMEuf@cLQn9gUeei/KhiKHMfLozB/kfMSYDuCi2wIpLk6rtlzoxfq0STKzp7L2sMP0EosRo9H5RHYALk6RCOEWaLtI49bAHAJKx6ZJO2O8cirVA61o0qJDmp5YwFf9RxY0JbaXEhczpi6sMyt1gof2Kk4XN9DwLe8RVKSw@vEZXHEg0sBxztjAOjP5SG1s4cAAj4G@D0prEig7/wFhyzgorGeSLA3eSR4KfgX4FLixmAzF3YjN4je/GW0j1sQSfUttkuXipYvnhh2iLz1vJdHF9Waef@QIHZwBdjUQuaY4bKAaxW3EwSkakjg8pUrndqg4Wj@KQYfTP3QEjaCLm@cMO6sStjEgNNv@9n2sxZDbr1ADQHUPahaePzZ2y3joBGDidmJtqHpCwNvsI5bRJQzIT4QRp7cADCz66iJ08IOomA9v3IGCUflWMZArUDuHHfDD7c6C/TC@z91oprPh5uzNNgQ4bHQorSrj1cK35EIWrB3Iz5T1DfDMA4ZLMNmIyQkAm5DjMgcdxL8enXO7RLKkzG5CSjKEIEgNUEhV8G9lZaHT6SXweGB4/LhMcVLZxcWFSkfmTVxLNT08sd3Dq2ZTo54FOrGTGpvDkbgby8I7EQXcuUnhFzXgBcQ7U7r6t3Rvxr@S1PWqYr1FLNr1otg4nuOB5L0hHbWDZ9x4xFCPLLrMoB0TS0Q4/@mN5KXPf2XkP6UYvUIgjCGYaXKWbCcBWLLVPkt2LzoV4XFOFRKAQymaviMeU@n6lqHnm6xRNwjhjGknhG9vDc5o5hEgyXzodJ40z6EfcuZbhX1kTSGSbV6wXdc1ZjHyj2NoZODYjNQeNoNmn3zACM0Mu@RnJlrT@qyxEH0aRIdGze/yMBfP0ZEu1wPlB2ii/5T7T8F/yv2n80T9ZOvTBlfJ0OkKs4Ncj8ev@SERzMwPc8UPm5z7EGRQrJnGQWDI2YLbFfzaVYrt05vboByrPmMAT4yA4GYsVf/itH7asD3zYquRSPWA2WUiBJQ4gK43iKYXncCM1B@cD0aOt@Bk46l70CoJvNGp3RfcwHkF8xgUEDEGp5eFB6X1hmK@nisEIsMAAfUw8ETVYHccs@KV4MBW8gTGqctzGnPE6gKZBmlfwku4gbrESc8JGwbUCAFC9yBLgCb4ML/m8Ps5fOnwwsVryP2wCl0pMMQDe6KNKFDyWlXhsqZChRTCSlF8NIHsqK5Wr2fF94eiqF/zCmXzSpR/GP2ND0a/C/ViOfbEsLzBqEjhqoIL0ECFENWFqMpq1VC5AgapLWNgutBy7XP9VLTWkMxWyu9m8HQwC94FXjoaCxV@O87Lh/amybZcDlhhVq1CFmdVXi15vfBJygkeRPNEtJnPCCI@FyAAI700mimiTcPRptUqFxxsuiLaRQjJKSE55VF46OkKJBsiGvSegtuqsXgaoJ3icjcZ4Gm8GQU1aCQzvHkUJ6Vf4WFiOEsp0pzLHOICwUOoYiOftRtLU6@HkA4JrWsAkBFvAOjwq77K0nWBpymBLZBRnJS@jOI2wQZcVgCDkQiu8AM3YwGTUR8YFH45Qe0A1F05UZdkjcZ18S/Nf3LSd/R/2k3H9GJIbdExnbz29w/i2EDKhipoSPvQ0lkUyNiTeS7uaF/QOSJ4K2bfAa2udeGw2BJlG9xT/vXuqdbAaaWGBi4EwQuAgkvf437/AedE2P2RMzbGTjZb5p0mi9huWfq8z2D1bAfPDQ8dtAu6XscxPTs6hkJtOz3b8swkXjPPVXaTliXwY8WlsJ4sjI4nSWIMkndjETTnK1R1m028krDZjOEitng5WClLa9qQPaNRCfu/YArFB/EkgB6OYk7rldkex2@HiWdCi2gnVvssdjgSnlFIZJeBDGuD/g@@fdBgmOfMe450Oi2q0q1xjC4U6DtDpwda38RTJYx9DfzBHDYiZIxGhEuSGdilLYdOBqdaEmsnjbiI@ukHR2Wf6jEjHsTXFwEsECPJ3Os0Rsq6S5JrrkyOR/PTO/5wfI/D@B6vx5d64ddx5l3zKvf8sKQzsTkECDhHI3M7Gph1kFudG@gsoBI4o17FI9wZxQ4ttOogprsQdFcEV7vAH8nA5oEtQPyzVfRfX4B@9P27Fp@B97Qez0DeDHH9X4yuFfD8yc0YBD@Ix6XIkuQC1n54x7QgLN6y8whVCFBjSXDZeLAmVMwRdLu94Lh3H/AtPI/rpW7wPS2iqnLPJTi550l2pq8uoofNjjkwZmYnJkImQ3D9HB9Bh43k1d0yjoKOhJ7D@3oxaLvigS8040h0Hqi8gmWM5Hk8vpqteBAr4B4aKScMD1bTD/1viGYc4qvy0WroB0SjERyOPbdw@HM0G8342c0DfkOHkKO8/eEliTvwbycI0EEcXZOcJxtfJz6PYkGW7tAiBGHVxSzj0ao@RDz/5WYZfhiJbs8pFG4oUtUvZWnxHoLlJW6tK/EQV/g8yeeN7saStzHdnXkuxGoc2FyE7X1YE3IDMq7HaLdjYYjcZW2JOfYNmYBuNE5nr2hVmksEahCTJN3You426RdxCXvGB/DFAafP4IsAe@a4yRnKzxuOaYlrWhj5DI1RSGsRLqCkA5QQFTnJBRqhUJJvhuCXV0Ga7ZVptm@k2V5IM6gBi0mGAknthSRFKWDxrCuCgdkdr5DO6IV9Z/isE9vw2I7h4mjFZdSKlq0ki55HyyCQo2a0vB8DoRztRMsPyeBFy8dkOIuWPwXDvG5F30bLfrXAAC5YyXAf3YUIR3s7Wt6Lxa@ksXFmen66arQclCmE2eFWogiQAvMNWiNOsdmOyObYNaFhI6UyyZBjvCR2n2gcJkm/NPzzm0XohgL0xDHOLQrMEkxbaDRCLQZPB5oN/wTsJTW5LFrz/cNHtJ4pCILJJKCPF45D4EENj0QXhRFHDH1pRgO@gCDKzfJyjFioJbsjOiJ14FAq5MX0iXoq6QOdGPnXIXBjnghdJyPi@@W1CIIX4N3wxMir8LyBjp8cYYRzsvElaCFRX0bXZArLehEXUfrhEqKx7sVAeNGxH4SXEoENyXTQ4WhyDhMbOaNFJiFfXAJvhePQoByvlMi916KRVBA1c4U3OYucoWAIV/74uuyE4iFqCyIIPevpBq9lQbtAshi95rIupKnyygcohGQO1HCzfUZX9TwURgrHxU2S2opVzZAflydJkmtRTEJkFY8SmhhjnnrQed3HA4Y@rPvqx5ziWEsMAYRiBqlw@ep8gP7ucP3dV6h9IlxLYJlivbwpvaler21lr2E@mCd7swDRM8kexpcqR0EKc5JD7yCkma/jtRsqPi754Eo@TzSAfk3b98kW9Aluodv1vgWHhVqCe77oeKaD45m@mlA3NZLBueorLSqmJODwjAeYzrO2Hlee8WVFjD40vm0MPriA3cUCDhcewqMMuNdIzmu5O7Fplcu8boPY5i4oUrUy44KcpkuDYp47grinqdtg2hYcDptHDw@fPv46NLqFQiEu2ujZHD@stTjWGrTjHDItjg7agyXdFj2Jt2/gZDcOx9Ol4huntnxDlnBhDcqAAan47CfqeFzIspA8v1Z3IR4PG6KogHU2rwbGglRCVcfAJtsSdB0DQcxxbMsQQHz1FuidpN5anO6ZaDbxIulmk5qvZhMXLzWbohXDovFnxOM/j2ykJp5LF1nyS1IuJInOAGAPD9mLT3ZP2Mkn@@zR871P2dcPn7MXu09PcC/3s@cPHh/sMfjtPz3eZ9LC8ki8UAo7lEDXh2bbxHv/8By2LCPIe85oxuVObC/O3Y@NIfvEaZs4TbXtGcP7fW5RbXNc47H2oTs6wzFMiy4NG1pjXG9BN15BNxaVmw5tscO1/AzCtqBPO8Q@79DpWF0LwkrY9x1Zpufv9GIDC0oQ5K2/wTbJlSS83IqWDtE1dLgC6wKiGxAe524AjMHXX9Fd3ZbHI5gdlQnCBc8HU/Bk/@jJMcPTAvYOnz48ODk4fHrMHh0egfXZ1w@efgz0PDg@OTp48By9KOCTw4cHjw72dsmBI5BWGe7XfzXxxmtRUDE4UaV9hjPfdCV7YFsc9UYNnl0YtNnQY9GJjdLHMgbWG7MTrUgTD9UX3OBIUwUstrl79PFn0OYz8zXOcPpTwbT@QH7u0SVrm2m2TalBZalBfauI6grNnqLFaT5iOGN454JZoa35MTInmQ@cFvF0LJPJe7hGBce@@Q5@qss@aEhoA2AjKH/BSpXRXSnRaHKbQNYgtfbAwTMYeWp8EaGwYNT7/lKTikQUE2tlECjuVziwcTxIqwQOwPfgoItkxy4PwDKBAw/AstwBVdEDXDvCciLEZHw4QfHM8tzh1XD0iKaFWSFweGBQL7YocOLlRkVqsOCuKTzPYEA34vBRHrqpz/DalkVRPAqPt8UMBrximPyeMpCJfCqR1rZBSBmETRenGsSyN36hJ/oCN@A6IaM79lisGlfZCS4OMm2L30XUGxg2XwI1X7pDvMeKeGJNVSyztYI7fGgHyMghBsT7wxbxCOI9FFqhedd4EPPBjRQNsUaS7tHzl6DdhsCDGwj8ImAAkLLQ02lTS0V7ShGM0xWsHPMc4Egct30XDg/s3Jm0zYUIYtVW7JX15k1cEDm50E/y1ykSdlBEb0wX1Eqayuw6LtRxEqt06wlKwXbfGY0tXoaxxRzQjBM1cxAaGzZI7WW1tpAa0uF6irZjhxJtARevSLUFTHmXVInj@dx5IL7mV2AC50MjzNfdITpGC68kn8@dJXES6cLE4RdQhGmuHAc/Z2PChOuf0lx2vGN4i16xWnv44FR59zKJV@lxscBvr/QXHeIPGBPTgupB83y0YNFFvUvUNP8KJG/SwthiDZ6QlljLfWDQD@xb0K@736wEfny58U133CNz3Z0c376t8lgKSiZxoanXj82lW5LV/SSTFKfBxBKQkOwEZEHWx3yXJMEM5PV93BeDpVABitgoR7Dffu2CISFC/Ny1Jl2QLOKeR1HcAfw4q9GKivm1t7izJVweqS9iD6qJWjw1X1DCQuSM@SI66UPW4vHQshRqr26Ae7geHMjvu4MrrsWONw8fBO3hWmgfhJuSWA2LN0shWHcH@24NWN64/UJgIe/J1YB5I3kTWsDpAXMmNyPBatr1Kb68UXZU9wAMtr04ghIADaU2sWmK2j/x@P8p7mm32siV/E0/hWiT4IZ22yaBJBiTGDCJZwnkYkgmxxBPY7dN3zG2x23AnsCeu/tjX2D3/z7Cvsp9h/trn@JufUhqdduQzMmeMzknuLsllUqlklQqVZWyXMAxwcQCUf1kr3p8LGzen0BZmPdwy9CW0yDCXhQfYmvbsE@TnaeFJr1Z1sKT@pKwaFP/HhvMc4n3wFQhZRBX0kNPFvEFz51wwrOeXFlIhCDre5oQFeWS2H1Vc1DUkIDvYQ8IyMadZjTQmtvMDC8@YWQagUu6uSwbmzb8ZGHNazfenjiamoBMmyC/i54l8/vvE8vHm6oeFrAwhA42uA2SNKw3sE@oQ8VDyOh5yR58pFtUl6KRPQvYGUU7NPwqJCXsH2coYiQWwlkWNqZ1KRxL1Fg@XlJiDhkk4jLgo6WnTGSLZkhQUzx92TI71IkXvWxyCQIhE@/Te2NyBRQ/vy/pG96z8TpZ1gK5OdaWCJuGwvIctbMSdunhTE/QFnojPT2kq4LZ9tGqcv8/VfEqkahJ0XxuY1QiQN5YX3/2LdjpVqjiuR@FzWtIev4cXw1hfx@DjKYRqfeBc2uHrkqPGeAR0rFpvRowqYIg6sxZUxJtp8XIxA9wYb0QIIORxvGKwnStjpikcJsPnVckEzplmWmDMYR1Q3nUzFD//vHqcEL@Zn2Lf7w@HmyYCU0H79Eq//1gFAWxV54RRcX4hP6ryW/BaNSnbOzPdIVQsuTG9KizHXnbscErtwoT6bzNbElHeiex2a2rdA1UCakXPbyVFLV7pbR6L1csmU3drx1UxQpFAOwkdJH2yHaMuWcx7D@GAM3BpJfA5YN8@J5Em/AfcHAVSCATefNliTbON3EjioDU3KDbX6RZqJxbi@ne70Qtv48hPVz7SSRs9ykUJC1s9WjfmadZL5QS5QG5aNjPQinXznk2FYVvqNBFSEkQ3Jv43Viw0FNDWUo@cpe8ny@@LGy8sqh1fXfsXjVenbsrrbItYPH1@1fR9ei2/Wt3cHnTET0x/OvFpDX9/Tch1p@LZ1DX2lOO/lrcKOcpdOYL@PtSvCoQ50oEX1Mk2zNbCI/vrxNiWcT78NKi4LvbaNO8iR4SKS4VK1eKC9HFbly@amycl/vlQumq0T8voZPfeLU8Xi2uZvHDU1hFYY7hk/nG@BzXVFPrGvRvBF5rStfPSdcQQa4h8OW9PwoHB5XDtwltHAoAqAKTtt6kUOcbSRfQmg19T7x@cJuVajJXIMdaKCBZC@QVVESfdtInozqmHQJm0CsuSLPRhP5OHWuh4F0PxwNKUcH9kLXEXXhnLSg3pgJpFCBLI1QhAOki9mgS58niwRB/nbIVda7I4loRfScdA0QDS9J0aJ/ZNvoUIqLSl6txbkVe4LcuEQm8gveOiomtLbqQF1gt8kiLh6Yc/ogcJgrn@IgHIPAzpNMGrIIk94jcPixoPr4X8YG/kI5qTH4yZCBvkaSIKWj@Lb6SfxOV3wICMOEXWObypIpTSl4gSLLvICkXMPBYcuOPxwzoVsmdsoCNRdhcXzkGTpbiRCOsVpIJvi/cIjmZVvBPtiBXpLeZZuj8DmcnktA5tXyLkJbUpZS0jT@9uFjWKJZTxVRmgxQL36QGarpge/Q@gGE1FbtBrwdIMy0WYnLgI/n3yvpXdf1RA@s818hzem4mPZdI9zidkYpzebDAx5k2zUx25muc717YcTZ3pq6yIOHFg55ueSCSxHlLj@WNvPGgGcaZt3VXMlfqhK1EQs5I@TKn9zllMVFGM7hOb3C65O812fMay0TeN8n68deSHRSQ8ay0NUlxqdcPe68teXurTEE2s4GaQnBx7G9iOx6U0gdTTicgwaGen4btdjmGslpUMw6NGXt7643tSSHjdTaNBnsxzgysOWPEoBLVuUqEm5DDItRDyYsGCIKJjCbUyN1Whaey8NQAi7kWVbXsBTkzwKFp6SFeRr/IO/yjBnsSOZUvMz9xgTGfcOPZuzlJIJp0F@35ZErOJuguwh9lox5ZReK6p2mI8yeJQ0MLrOsM2Ae7g2rwRT1PmBOFmilm6K5TJKXjDEXFvg91ISbeW//Mr1hvfZCxh71gIiq4zfDJC8tKOLiPg2gcYWwnikUTXQ@HPTx1JIHvllyoZaCQtXU8bokhGiu7Z9XQsofzu/gkHdKhkCeOEPItGojECdF1t4vOZOgBO7jFqRU1LuHYsyr9KSs0YMw8W2M380BcR3xqCrv9rokE9xyPHqR0NPRbgWeBjBaB9GNxUzuhvF2R9OnoN4LRw2BJ27Ssv1yHrV933@J57oti4VnRINmNPA4ueM@exw5WQCSVsFYAMXa9@NyyjLPhFp8N5xCgKw5wof8IvBncBP1@YFVgxaCMEQitUTC6CdqeZR0H@hAY4SIr48kk@mEPrkctVu6A0OUDM6KXcOTycRhwGP7i@szHxS06K3MtPLSKT5uhq2/CNhJQeZx0Bng6TAcWGCaA6YGFroIxEGXFEUmU6OxZ4kKyyxUqooAaGOfEOJvQZOgPxmELeoY0WVYPQPExSFxZv53CBOpr9Xx0DvbmIYDuMTEFFALqKOkxHCx5aP6HcBCyYeqM3Vc9k4fZb0BjBYZ7MAph9o0JTL1CxQzcoYNP3tXqon60f/KpclwV8Pzh@Ohjba@6J3Y@0xk3HpRTBFvx7ugAZhd9ms6n5kfwwa7UoaRNCVbl8LOo/vzhuFqvi6NjUXv/4aAG0AD8ceXwpFatu6J2uHtwuken7wBBHB6diIPa@9oJZDs5cqlWVcyKy4mjffG@erz7Dl4rO7WD2slnqnG/dnKIleGpfkV8qByf1HZPDyrH4sPp8YejelVgw6y9Wn33oFJ7X93zoH6oU1Q/Vg9PRP1d5eAg1dCjT4fVY0FGAkYrd6qAZWUHtrBYE7Vzr3Zc3T3BBsVPu0A8QPDAFfUP1d0aPlR/rkJzKsefXQm0Xv3LKWSCRLFXeV95C42zst@gCvTL7ulxFeMfISXqpzv1k9rJ6UlVvD062iNa16vHH2u71XpJWAdHdSLYab3qCryhjqoGGEAtSIfnndN6jehWOzyBNeP0A9o7ONDJn4AwgGUFiu4RgdEMAlsLRDo6/oxQkQ7UAa749K4K34@RpkStClIBLSp2T8xsUCEQ8cRspjisvj2ova0e7lYx@QjBfKrVqw50WK2OGWpokPEZWAcqPaVWYz8BXvwIzGopznWpO0VtX1T2PtYQc5kbOKBek9xCZNt9J2nuYTRcQ4kSDlBn4F@ZipXO7KebAINLzmpk5utodMSk3aO9KqzIMliVHSecwqrzMhVKyUyDlUYnwmsiZE07uLjuNsN@Z4A@proYKz6uoq6LV704eOPFmfXIjRpSv0IFMplm82OlCRvderPpuN9TMoHGt0pINfhjuRzZRgzcjztvVPxsbjLdtxKE2n4qDzrJUA8PIDAnU/8pm775V4Ej8vl2IIuh8z4CVqqjiI9NLvEoBaZGcnbEazniKkkzQe@hZAcqmFXgvVYT9aRoGUmZBhH86d/FL7w4GB9gdmZ1Vz6Pm1hCI/w9UNVwJRQSgf7IiARhh6r0oiD4tZstmNXhnt/rDgbtrOOoMpR3DPvAbtb5RvGLoJsqnkuXJ2Tp2FlGzI/UvptEGH3@LEkmZL94I2pZFv80x/TjKGw45gNqTakqUlZLpWX2KRdHiyRXyNAW6F5BnYwy3/vKz7VPuJsrrD0vpb6/0995bKG9IAahhQWvQeXO6efdOWeAAUaxOIAkoYyQkc8bZZS9ic58CxkvMdNt2EbLH1irLwNa14EkIMhe@z2zTlyNR@HExB7m4bfHlfc7p/v7MHUits9frr/YKFk67NbPLv9@xnooUixFHRvCOg5yGiUZo2QXBB8aKUYs7Zj9iYHzecyI0dRVp9FHjPOg7TaSlkw4kWFzI7yjpo8menaAdLAFBeBYtBS/zh2ZkgGyiaY62Jorf0Iivg@yEvGANGbpTanXJvgHYevhr4a4bpBkIMliFDsXOBd2FzTv2fvKVJQ2NxS4B7N4tuJjDuOmaUCqLrKfRe9aepO8bfRixKaMOF6p26kkILGYxkIou4o@j@wPFGdEKoApehh8@VnyGzx@lgHuKNydH40r4zqQcV@XRD11rIyWjW5IyOfbZeiip091TVsCtfyORIrGnlQn68AgxmggVPCuEbTxTQIu6Tgi6SrJAvbNsiO@Mqdi8A6EU5IcK9@Bc@c1R0Ipqfgh8l1FpRAMSwc5Yard6josleWzjmOhyJkg0w/Rg@D/iTSZA38LdpwAPaaWEQTwuyhJUJlWsH0looS36qDBON2IqWl@@hyDuTc75lI3TJ7eTNi/Bkgge2eqPnymsIed7BwCIJOjYsMcv9ok7dKHrdMb25HF8Zyk37oaZoVcK9RSMQM3t3HuktjlqrMVfHGEw7omo8IDKCre8MbtgkY9bJlSW3nxJLIZnKPif@RXSAGiBzxx6SVbraY5qyBHmZoHZKglY8Fp64hJIJbeP3hqtyKMEJmJuV@efClCAehtxGe2nXTNx0CweW4y4iKtxOKEouBhPHDcJuPiI0PWXZAhZi9AOE/apAzBm0DGt7hA9Bg6heqLoYnsEzIUwUpiq8M4ziBOt44HpKVl9VZjT5pJ5FCN/WmfA9EHrNVSOTwO8CExNN3lPfHenwLKve9rNrNYfqU@cNF2EStjtYQsj7eetAaDEYiOPrYbcHTDqeOJT1LpEPSj65GMXwjrWTiSGgkl9EM1KDbx7p2WGY4BT6hF4Ri9Fdoe8Qc16SpAC1EOTzLJbYgsMK/i0W2ldAwnq0WR3YpTtoAmFJaUiLglNsTdHedigsqQoQFRMIz05oJsNqkePHfQw@92MPoV134UgfrtoK0jkxogSRfInVTrU4zH1pibPhxEpNGArkANiKZEkRVp2lAV1ugXkp2kXZMdR8fE2KXUkj9ej2ZSZS0FFcWMK2sH5tvIQWcildZkaFAdLLS4tk6ozNtw3T@4GaNooclja2Gf9fWUsslCRPmJEh3xiedN/fQZn6SSv/wkwtEDX/CMW4qgiDDKrHiuOjvPEX5oU/ApDEZtUycKkkzbH6L6jbY@gz7xolIdyrB/LX8cBVPYAbTy4SRPMJrZnwaX/ebuoOd3w0Howz4Nw7hPeMbDxyk9Yod1R4PbiC70oYS2kak9jZ85vgyHYcN3fS5ZMkJzReNgmDXNFMajaeWSw0SQ5hyNAOO7Jom/h@kYabrM8/W4kJX0PyV7vKJTerDss@K8wnyijwDkBLedsqBgH9IxOSYZzqelmQwXj2UwcLwQOeE7D1jsJTB@BSSiY5gExgqZGbMEsxG4M3sQ40Z74rYpBuEIAy0FewFeORNl6bPr462@MIu8RkuBTVF8WTCK8inKBOMQ4sP0YXKvvfiTsQcEfgD94rN53DKPEWiK66hoSxHvV2SUUcCFzANDmqNpJoZZLOzCKtRLAG1O0lCTydOHqEGWPyAUyTB7M1yJIzILGx@8Iy7bhCmnOXVwUVkWyw7F7UARpDLOFh5m2OBb9rM0@PEQlzVnODHtSshZA@mHSNUCKuEFpinzWhNljqn87RGztva9vZYiYHmeyZlxUW/WVpILeaCEvL7isdZgBJOxnaKeNPVYjsaD4fJ3Uu/BuWNuZLZ5tG45zjcNgZnZyrBYrrSJtOUpPk5LVhqfFNMkKUaWZsBDuH2lZ83maSJOyk0cb@Xm9Bt0eIhmsd2UXlR0f7d57OOieIMWvWqh0UOKcMcgpSX9vdGEhjcfnkEkTN5eNWnGaOKU0ZzyowEqRSZNpe@nEHGfxD1FjzZQDuttA@3M/nmQqGkjORXyVCUlglwiPTFwOzptwrw07KDxBYaJYwlXT1Ja4Jy4UzrKK@YuMMgwJjBAlIqDXKyHYg1u3FkpPqLbATrZJloLFXEmgqdt08JBB/3XBKOo/FK5Iy0emtNc8bzEkCYaEuwqKNdjkJS/Obw2mhOCMkMKGOJzSKFbNDM3XX5/q360LZAPIHBpSpaWvgUXG@OIVcAG/phJzQnKwHFVsmRiRCUHQpOmBhgLsEvp9gLerqL0F46Y49G6QQ4j2EDw5yz@rMoSGM57o6CpjUUm7SlmcSS5ebQ5IrfNRWKG4nckvxyKLOrSxhUABIwxlC8XAQKGNSXs8VCAQu@YnJdAVPYRFCwXcVjCR4qKGtt5zklHosoMz9eNHIV5OV6ZMHJzgYBgMT9PjAjILPOzxFBgoZuLi5Hjxfz2xDlAIFa8zxSHrpC9kqSh7jkmIN1dXHDiGaVRFG5BcjAlPl93Eomavyn1VcFILaRTgT4aw0aumE59WUikJqpdW0sWTZQEejhmrYlEIIVjIqxnhR/7R64pZshzbRNqbDISUoa0z8a7pWGXCfs276@R2CKnbCVjKHimZ7jafjX5ipVEUPbHA7CLZToywNjtP9xaZZmqMJF3BVBcOuXskuUNIUmsNi712Czc6apIezpAgdrTDjri48n@fiLs68VUGRpdBaP1QqGATHxhBr9XttWoSgoH@WTufOe618sPb38afbzI09wfBHQlwKbaQQfQJTAoIm8w6vLNEIgDZMXcOenIinv9607HvIIBTyix86DbOKeMhiBoAQq10cvHE1IAEUi5wP6CDcT2/SL06Lv1WdCUUNQxFJRGk@AbW52eAXnwQwfts/VJFQHDiVlZM8G65ZS3v@IKgjebUGdR@GLna2yebL8Ler2BKz7hlcAYKWDhPl1gf98sUOAseMJI3r3XEcWjdUVwE/YMv2LMYvI6glMLk7pnQsWFx9j4x0G3Ohlm7cYXG5YVaPIqNnMV41O7wu7ajgwW/x1gmQ8B7e/KfeUPsy2iUzozLPVyBMdPgNGzojt375PI4pBOTNLs27mRqPPR9ShYAzTdIVlAxbKn7qWWPJBdE9c@mxQ7SMMCw5A4YcyV7yuBrmZ/3rR4M@50vm9WpGsAuGP/0IzIN6H82IRIZwA0AuXwA3piFO1/ycGw3k8FFGEBBy/rmJ13sEATC1jWk1b5t9tspVIRS8PVVVGp7MBDLicqOxWxhx92dsQevO/g@9Py2vp6iefcPecrfNxRH@/FDsAgDedq63K0B6@QVka/MbTWxi5eypeX3NJSs7y1XYryjcoOuvXD0z/@7T/@8e//ma/Il//Glx16aXzRmTzPyy@1vi49vS/he2PvfHnporE0PF/ulpDL/klRwwe1cc6PzUe90YWV4VXA@Ep2pGqfTdFnZFGhbvW78ke/wuyyKTKtKJ@RXyO@OYrm2EwrML4H6Ed5AVt4delAeisPSGQA6BTV8dA7rQAN8GC9AUoCLmgHyuX5bEUp7jEcjM6gT1UyMhIPyaw3Afq0xJEU0BcXVqxc2I@CPmrAb0jm5eZZlg@/4bgp@Tf/5X3U3RlMxMpZVqwUxIorVmybfoobr@Crs5QP0TuXs8F2wLZdSImPFtDMUEQhCXq0f6C7dlLktqwlurIHIakwFZSZveBcvfsjZxm@cC3qWgt4aaZgFQkdMmGRzNel/j10y1fIcW8nXG1IUGjKXQxVZpyo6P5FEciP2BAgrvmKCbI5gCrxpI88kvEpr77IvrboNiECjGQ9frtP4x4/wFq01Jc2z4m9FF5zRObz/BXXxhI7QxPamML1xwjQgQpvJwvkSbicWbbYyttoJTWTvbDN9knmY1uHaTBWtulc6F@FwQRszW0Sbqkv/VqkITcfrwg71McrRlV22vZbWEaRq@veOBxKdwWqHQfUV13bPY8k7FECxHA4Zv/m7AgjRYGKFJXqFr4sayraA2w6j4S@dE2HDnY8PjkyiJD/koWxfZca206evEQUOzAPEFLalK/jh71IRl0ZEbG7/ugCbwf0O3Sh2pjPzUifh9ekpjAedDTSHkEmk/N4PENTMsOR373yXZE5HJyM/GkNli2QfMYtz4EWYggmRAIHn6x6XvMUwtwi2SVEEd0UshzCywt6U3k9GvetrX1OsEvVUJBhV3AQJNiJKBncJfoqRceYq/9AJ5goz0ze@jRSTrE086KlkYRkm24zNMxmho6lajDHjh44tsWo6pGpeEEWusaF9ooOfmEm72GMAFm3Lb0ApSvCxiusH1enbtD3E4vTsGcpR/98SfC6iOOZrqJkayRL3XxajG@8Q6xAjvySjALBa5MKZ2QtZLMLZ5G8zi1jriMU5Fvb4ud9EeoL6OgCM/IMEaf9kCfL1AoV34HhiRpZ/gOETs/vAn7TW3@KrHiWyb5ezDuNL2f985XsWf/u7HeHMJFTslplcyIjD7PVjCXHCqyMeTfxqqzSIhVq8KyfzHDWF@zDYpAAEMlnG1/y53d5QOgsg3fKn2WYIIkuQ0zyj9eXR/D5GTQzSSzyGWvBWXFU52dfFx0Bayv9Yh/yB4d/AQu1qSQ1PexzRh0ARX66v12zy0mUf7lWeL5WfA47oW4wyY2Ca1xvc9H1RTABUSLC7SwsPWe/J7ghQYj7SeSX4OME2snXmrDvSSSdlOQUKoc51WNptoIyHvME5AcqU7hUdHFxdB4fDx9xw@8KYDmVl2JBsemgwX1ZXD@jwRXW40c4r6W9Q5gj0cqAbURIhZpDyOrylYc41FHDZZn8nDyxi7FbCQh0bz5jrBb9QT8nhTXHWy6hEI1eM72XhZeF9BidGaKJEbokhanlRVHcfv3i7/919FtmnNley38awe8481tm42WGH@EB3p6pt5vMdmYLs23cZ6Z52APD44u//w@U3/4J4GDKdAv@bK8rWBvTzHauTEXuMtsb8FBcW4N6//dvf4M2LPGODe9iXWq6ghArKYrs@n3iXUgXNWwlb0uX42mFHLMQBlsYwt4cXtAwarL2skBquoy0qrgJZOQrZY8il3gyzBqTqRBrMpQ9BUhGXKCMFeQYpDKh6AjDdkOZbSDzxmiKX554GxHsAH6R5hy6Sm268SRCk6El3hZBB2a5RtjP88N24bWtzTs2bWVTUlIiJG7t5Fz78lnp/wA)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/q50we)

Halt instruction is 0x76 `v`. There are several `v`s on the first line, but luckily they all skipped with jump instructions.
Note that 0x20 space is jump in Z80. Z80Golf code is on the second line:

```
>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v
```

```
ld a,'3'         3E 33        >3
callnz $7E80     C4 80 7E     Ā~
...
halt             76           v
```

I use 0xC4 `callnz` instead of 0xCD `call` to avoid zero-width characters ([insns](http://clrhome.org/table/), [utf8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)).
`$8000` → `$7E80` to make valid UTF-8 sequence. Memory is initialized with zeros (`nop`), interpreter executes `nop`s from
0x7E80 to 0x8000, then prints char in register `A` and returns to the point after `call` instruction. So `call $NNNN` is
equivalent to `call $8000` if code size < 0xNNNN < 0x8000 and memory was not modified.

Answer (score 5):

## 337. [ReactOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactOS) Batch, 15030 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a a a  z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy4iiipsddpsdoh (22)S2&:&echo 335&/ \&exit&rem ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//n&goto e nthteo18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1t@.7.8.2<auaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMM M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
*/
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit





























































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata#8;>0::&&1Pr"9?3"sge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[s]pogr61!\0k:4op>astd+4[]!!tfc;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1\'ull 
 
*/
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD40dHw/IgjULdIigRAgG9SpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdun1JFgskQRJXJMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj2@7ZzzbXk/EeCd21u0deybC3o8TjvnkH1B@bGw4Ntz/oDczDwCCEklV@RGxsbGQCBycR548efLkyTwvtHS3/7OfRfBiz@zBrDewx2xsuGPWccxzw5HZgxm7r5tuVksLAsbadXqToWGN3ZIQYSpj7lh3xmygW72J3jNYBHw1Nn/vmoOx4SSZaxisZQzsCwhPM2YZF@zQapsdgMTG9plhmW8MB8IyjD00BlfDqzFr28OhbnVcNnJMa0yhWcae6fDSnbTPmN5yx47eHpu2BUE5xp5bA33Y6uiMoo8cgyfKMwDVPqM0iyEFxp7YjmtADnbbcF0bPYvgqTum/Xj36cc34qsp9rEOSI0GxvRG9qrKXpiG07mZQmOfnh4c3PRNs08k22IHt1FSM2x3MrYPxzfhZ9luz7B0pslFWbsZmANijo1BIVVILQRB2IHpQG3qXq2V5jVjTYYtwwHie1V4YY77MiQ4tTnBmW0NZsyYAjDAsQvRjDEzsbZYNpXCmPB/YrRtqzMHD14GwAG4xnA0njGJWbbHAxBkO8wd6W1D6hgDc2iOjQ4bmICd3fWwcRlUODszZhe2AxUvcVYkRNyR0Ta7JibxSuAKyGwPjdakx@zJeDQB9FzWMV29NYBorRnrGF19MhgnWQvCgHjkf9E3LA8l0@phOV7MfRCCBU2AY7@pAm3MwYABOmeIDmbtsm0MuEB/jNoyCEujg6D25@QCSPrA9Uu/mPFCNpjumWP3HH0IjNoxiAafHj5jbtt24A1@GJe3gnVg2vqYbW@z6P7Th1FWDcgoOy0hIGmFXTLGIn4gO9cHE8NlQ30GeVtjaFzMpvrzUwgQnUU3oiUWTaeZlmKZDMtAYyswLZti0CSK4IBWq6VV@OWYVmAZFfg@G01iPl1H75kDg0Pp2YMuAsojx2pZpsE9lWFptRBN8hhtyifP0gWWy7N8luXhXmRFDTJCqBmmFrPwy8EPoBQBCxV@6QzPLWANZCkoBttjXX1oDmYc@miE4Nssq7I8QARUVYCsFQBCUUMIi1cY3rgPxO3r5wBSGphnKDKMQGpgjSnwULa2FBJbKB95lm7fGAwwVyAWkClbYHnINQcFz0DOQEutoPmF7/Wp@IRXPgU/wDEPJS4AiVNArRSSKw8/eAdRpIHM0UDAaCAzNBX8NXCnESrEy0FYDuorl/Ghax2iLUhYSKsiMVGoqEgDSAaVwNJQFTmWgSpOYxVn0wzwBATyOQZypaCyQoYV8gzIVUwxIL0KyGD9qyDPVEBCRWBQrSrUqwqIqMAwKgBV01kmhOiqpjEc0qYhLZBAzUCaDLihXtQc/iAdVLwKWaqQp6YV5@wFuGlZKGQ2TXyn5aDy8hAGxNIAVw24RQNstQKEY9oCEK6AbJn3CaEPRn0daQE1gMwMrAYEyQJOBBvig1vLpzlLUeyWMTbbPHWLODiHTJ5DUkLSFBYRnhmkKKCTAjDI4FAEDWo7jW1BuBagWfIuNCyyfPGDIgTEEdMZ9sDAvXPWiwUiNA4SbVHaTVxjACwIQqitgxt5HsQFih4fjjmWUVBDP2fY59gTk/xYyMYlGdNysBsGgdcxHIdhXOit3SRJI3fSco3XE@ys53h1QbwZIJm7ujkIEKB2p4@pI4Fn1IX8Zotodx17SI1ziNJmYNujFXIbZNsFAnpkXxhz1OeiTx@NBtAhgL8BhJjoA0DmQieFgvSNcK4cIUiE6dp9EwBSViCYTcdoE@29okPqNIjwRRRLTKveSyOUB6F@Jc1GNkhlF9NYk8GgBP2l0WbpqtIxzhX04X3PYp@DOPi9EXSoHoiWDsoA9caIRQDpniZTP3fq16xrDxeLxmXTYVD0vol9yOBCn0HtdUEsGVN9CCoLQ73Agp5/CBzDaxBrwuU91yHr2FZ0HEC5cKB/hkIHJQGQA6LJ2BwaoNDZkARrPENIo2QkzFozYGWiVkYmfY5jcoNQsnCTUNwjE/LgjQV6xs6kjVTDvE2LOAh6FBeVG8fQO9xPGDusXtfh50DXN/JUWRkdGPEEUQtpWtBvGkB9T6loE0TUdQzLBb3JlZmJCiZwfs/uArNRZw9KCySdw24TEZAEgddUbssCkRwZaHg2YCZrj0YM/EHTAfY8SBWgt7a/MNkbCBz0XTZoTxxnxqYjqAlzCLHGbbvbBe59Y4z6AIINO6w9a0PzhEpG7hE6Nkmi9mixmPO3TQPiWAYUe@/Z11nPALJD394FTInl5wUYjagIRArd4v2@pQOlsAjt0YzIAmCCFF3bltG/YxsuMQvoRUHTx8xco0dNA9pZdy6MhqjHAJeCbmEB74Lk8ZoXwscMhaWFwaw8LvjYsKDptIErodFD9WGd7rIuWBGhLh/VRL3dNkZjj09sEmemFVKNjg5QNSJfyQMmu31h8z5odYtcA1EDzgnpAfoZSVk0GUhj01HWeqYKaAaWESjDjEuWwexW9hDj/Ebu4iuMs4DBK3EFDiNqEqgnkpCYjFGUoHQ0232UhWOUNqSrQGtzJreLD37h7J0hk7pB3oiNCmJHkJXAC/FYDUOC3@A2IHk0QFjVBQ@MuuBxB2jdHS6BbAdIDjphX1nRZRCKdwEd2pa9BCoQM4CLURZDqC6IGU9QauiDgBmpubgLdYQCe25FY0cGfehoZDvQMrjQmaFI41UW4i6bWzyxoK@IgwW@2LVClxHFDn885tbbaAAWFTUxbKmgleogKUCIcVsCZJ7NcwwhTK2eYHn4XZDo58wEfallGajY6s6MA4HiQfcMGc2Y6TggBs@xk@B9kN@ZyMSn0CfonQ5KViQHtfubmcvI0XuTljm9abC00VP@whXOdYd10VZxQOmARhSLdt1ovEz@lDIUJCr2aKxQUn4XISJFkqHKY10wf6CTOABBczKz2jFxoYmJSSZOxt2CGAcHJuQ6GvuqPhrfxO4L8EOmGZ5Bu6a3MutB9y1JcJfQjzDBAEXGAN0BPQMaIejqxWKnpbMrkB4Ok6Z7lBqVS3qqcibIy7A6QV4eIRCXcHllnoXrtMkhhXo1LAFGp5JTJ7FAwPekBCUUwUNRvL4VPUjb42Gk13DPiUUDDSzGVZE4uwwUfegAYoSMCcqH2TbHTU9duXfPV1w2KhVgNtCmQGx24mETwR@RkUFSQ2SZtBEvE3lsn4yxbcTiUF6MfM2xAbUJOLVSZZfjvgMtjt6vBYgEZBUs5GSfsF49PzXPJp2bFW2hJ0YSsdWB0mS2x2JZgM6ft4bKOqpGF6gKJkQUqYrMi@kJ9C3mJV@sUNGL5hguqr8VD5VQDccQA49Xl5KIJ/X85gy9N2sPPJWAu6Cxc2nUAvTPPJs/EERJTyfwG@2tlsqBYHPgcNiz3dNHFa8t8kClZVqlBY@B3dYH5L2J0UU/7ePDB8e7x19vLoExMFulmx6KmSnksKudTKWeNVEyslbaDMOYA37YXA8bEy7GEQUvmEn2NKQqzdrQuUx9ch4df3KTJKAJITkoB3Dj74ZKw@OA0iW0dLd/oxNmvUQCsgyS@HGZdMh8mIEDUcdw3cfn2eTNG6y8m0iNPH/EbDDROQDfUzm0/HQyBt5QwPygVpf3iJQWtFDTwpHUuSsc08fnY9SabyJDqnSIZT4@Otg/rhDYvu6eGYOBRFEUdwy6lO50ZOD5waRjCMvigPgDV5sl5DniqE8TrksJ3G4vEHhet2wFfACAto5sM2kw9Ivm9gH3vZtlI1@pHXAAvROEm3plWB9qfyiiITywi2ujybusF6WAeWcVeC3tsYLQxW6rnc0a@Uwx3G2153l2wkCHpBSbtq83OhB05kroI8@1SE@t9tA/eXwLcZeUSDAFJB8zd8BkyssdCGi9SCaLusoeWGj2wJBfkMQTmRhXlKg/hCq3XTI@Q/H3p@Y4lorzpxqHuJD77u6h9tCP7A330UgGGQ1oi2PP5HRxyqLtAo9Y9sDu2WwL0nDt0M8Q1KaVxdzt2datGtLRE4sawTkQkL84cKOPoK8x35DhSKnC5iqfP9Et9wKktJpLI5GIQgRKofjyF/q5DuSal/vk8PN96ETUbCoVuFN0AQlCaYhc6GqHfMmDSZCR7OGztIDBfMit1u4HSKEJCSy0J@iChLvz4KWeJDFlZWn8pSh91b5F8S/s2Q3WAh/OWuAIkezw6bPHh0/3n@x@Vh9r2ezCeyZVzAHhIL8W6EJyn9MNW@sWb5pYLAQXgbbhYPMCKTABA8UfWJ@4DghuGaPIHIEVXMNnkmJftftW1I3fLMwFhkpfWG3OQk@w8fGoXkIwtDsDNEYcPgGH/TnyT388HrklRYFW3p@0ZDBalS/a9kDvKZQOOobBQFHRdDk8wnENd1kKQMadGTwFH9wC1WFGI4j6YGiD8UKTeigaWIyDp1Grgdnrgy2MM3@GE5cDDqbSKB2wEMBWVoKykQCmN6Ct9/TrSeSs/RVVK3C@VlNaRhH9aAvNH@JudA0wnWLQWwEp4jdeWf1e/R6bgZRGSDeBRJi85U3@YF8wYKBI0qgp2vk@cUha4Hgpygqi0esJjuaClFKyqUxezWUVMMvATAOdVcIxN2moj9t9aWxLAE@yuzRuEOLCrtvWra685Tl8ZEHv@wiKmq69rNetBijo9XuEG06p1WaNmtqIl9ntJFte/HgZuHeheMi7vgfwLjmBNenJVsizjn5bnHV0al0dpoyHI6/PkUbsyS4oUm9skNcdI9z2MIESDlS2FuIqGPmtsmRAaIBJBbwhpRRoUNDTAuspiJcESi@qh8A5ILdCCdh8NIOXg09kh@QIGt3I96YddWnEH/UaHC11R0BEGmxuo5R2cXxwDL1jwPkopaFyUUizCyOK4@i6y0crIZE3femnB1stgECj8sGItBVM2wITUCoyz0FyAF/hsGl/PsqIRj9wGmRIOOHgA2gQFs0e9EDOQGJekF1eEJ4T@SwW6cyyLyyE1jJYQWqZYz7Yb08cnBY0O@GyQfS0xuMANCpcSK7T/GHLaPNRVp6YSgFGoM6GxtDGoQTQrkgUGFQEnc89oi3o4og1NKuUhNMvAF9i9/dAirUNPl4kDdGIApbaZ9Gxo@xKnyu69Aa4eY1uhYXfDU@FU6Wf@gSgkchgLpxGSbwRUNJO7CFFekHjLRj4wFd3hdFs3IcSA4eJesUeGdZNm49bhLF4mWZso1EQ@KYVu4xubGxES9FqNAmuHXBto2sHXQlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKZLkwtAapUC/RvS65kOexhvIA1PUHN6Yo5heK5XSjaReU72nhs84VAVQHmJL@AA40Xilgs54XKxe4JwN6O@hsu8h75y0HXPkkeCroBDwd48GaSICmPeozTtGGW3T9RQZVhwwGg1UMWNOtF5L1Rv1y3onUb@OJjF1vKxXwD4E4TWODeWeY09GoLjVMiUJZFu8li41yq1KNBXdisUK0gAy0uPxjwrxhM5pHYsawFOxej0KJPWoU2v3HYI3TWrxeEAowKNrgpUxGMSi8mUB8m/FG/FEFNLGo0kQy5VoFOjSRiK4VGgcEeBMdGBOgZTQMKGLC88pkICkySlsrp8bo/7MCUcIRt1Ay8YR9Pm0PjQGkuJhKfmGpw8rdAuWvq/38nig3OLgHepLoxmX7gLHtK4sLDHx@91zqTu0x7ryqQxGkxzqLqMbUUWSoCekEA6Jiv3EdLEJ65ZhT9zwSOPSAVDMHXxP@xMQlv76myRwlTkSjHbfZtHN@wCdBfM92JXg1JXEJ8B8AJ22DD8UoqiV4GQJaBe0MMUEuYiLVviojEpIcNHjj81nc6PXcpBbmdKwFGZk9izbMSQgCaQQaBkJLToSqsxbm3JII1@35iW8UOrS0PA2DZCIBwNbJ9pycR2aDxoNQ@nBPockx0ZHGID86IJ4lHldOEZH2RJoltZ2@tBDQGlQEmtBbQ29AMV2Rx15PIWkQgw73HAgt@5A6bxgHU3Tcu1st@SHIVcAsftQSWiVWmDi@kGSCoFxr5L3@bCQb6M/PXq4z8dOqLPF7hXH0ZpDuzMBvdKzm44Nq5dk@8BPpmUPTSCDn/7N2eDYtsfcyoeXVSMz3Gg2h5OBTmM@N4dl1qZr2y17QENB65LO408cVx/ofBDKD9399Ano@s9PTypyKRRJ0c@Ha/PGccjl2XJ6HobnHGm@1Z8ecjljiptZEfstf1kbihkvIIcBE29RG9SR759Hf79J4RyK519A/yEuaANd2RtFoNfA04tYpIi4yA3XBnmel2rqGv1X2mBBPJXiccVxju2lqpH/@bjbXfBOk/eZhKJpMPfOkDdf7LZgI4ZRyvJIuPJtIU4YUI7iBAvgbsbzhFew1qBvDPwZxGNQTHCWDPr2AapPYJugJs5XoRmgSI9wMoQkNE6xsTbomu6tYQtoUyOJxxYiG9ROoA9TUHMRNhXmDXGXqaVYtjc16XLpaYNpT6Mn21U@mY2mk8OtNoUPvm82AcR2teyvSVoVDXOKRoNoBJVwgxRUTJq/v1XUYDWGS2PqAiUpC64CVsNUS0n1aX6/cRVVXCJDl4n1@vSjlPYZmB@4fmzzntIzypjhKnqV/ZCop6q2ZkwCxQ5j8fHpdh/ECUtMF0kJ9TOxuvagI/HJMOALxs0orCBvLUKwro06AvAxHX9Jm4mrXLylhyBGQ6vhbsG9UaXV2xFC6@cCQNBKLtnVWfL8itWgZzuX3dHAHDfYtTy2m30kyXjiWDdX2nFV03H0mSt4S1kqbPf4409rqQaHIAx1nOAq8Fqc@gs1QT8GfQjXw4ILF@SMzTF1@LTgwMTyqjIgNaW5EEAfYPAMyizIyCsRon5lXM3L0jXAII0ZiLk7GyaZEb@WuwN9PDYsznN8lnE1ufl0kJdNhbLf8eYWSixFEzCggJoYBiiW2cnpw/3jYxk4141F93GipgTNUW/3QQ9ZVWifkuHCl9hHnSj7CNPE0ToXoKmBkdH00gNTl4HpwcyA3FFE9AwnBp5xnGNpgzdNa1FCroh5BMJlVe0x0SgAFjPiUCYCVlqK/3OLW1QeniXg@ARREsgdu1cC2ppxeWKZr2UX@hNSTyFKlNuktAi3shkjsbapxol/HHOIc8RgSpF2CGWo1dgGSD2KLbLKW/aylpKKjcQmazTKfOYfEqKuT4t6vQWiukdPPk1GgtPD@dCz1ro3lgn7OdCILqbi@KnAs4LHt4AsNeZbrVTc1MR4gKz0Bjx4oHgTySXLWDmK/tonEiy0VGpxydPigqpQsZ6T8X1j@TkUx0cgKA9OT8Z4KdlGhanxuI8ZB/RCd9CkLrFntuuarQGtj@0OTL5ULOjESx5hPEg@ZcLZlbFhEN2wPUM7w8qYL4rmS409SlA4dUBgYWHJyCMWZ5dITCKlhlRkV1foIbJNjREbiLgmmdP32rd1QT4@tgHZx94a67AuQkLDW7aCoqMuiL5RtzgvjCHcYFDOb@jC0rkYTsd1UdM6s2l2KXA1U7KaRf0zSD08G9xO2TXdPt0WogY48LjaKuzcYatLtyURaJLFm74nDxq@9zRvqE5dOaYHjeQvyXlxycpCti2jO7F6NNeJbia9viOmVCxQ5G6rZa6KCkTAVWj@c0k0kJXY8jQ5I6t@68GBH@gWQX5yW2le9JurndgC3aGTGkMq7/lfv9EB@t@unT70VzjOGTiaoEFgTUndlZXlJcUXui2vWD4cPxmYOhGGXHeBbOsOFEkfBI7loGnKX5JACxniBIZX48CbeAMddQ2bccz5/KP/XJ7Jsik8C@R2e1XcG6u/eFY02QRmZIeIwHUx06BEJGR5JRhTPuETMuhR4N6NlL9EixEz83rvT8YTfgc1@c5KNEf4W9c2vZiprN5SDTBU9ZZprKlyRz@bdGxpdNYL1OXckrjz0tOMswRaiTf53ETn8uLzAjpmD7p7/7kq2rx/VS7ocRdXuNbEHUktsvk7/I0awnBNDs6A31dFMb29UIFjNdXMAd3ekxM96MAo3toLBVe2SiGimTfIPNBbM1SF@h/OZcE6BpA4lXYikUqvmMgejVanR7uV0heLy1NP5Tanx7IRCYWvnpX4mB0V2FtPe0etQndlDvWBpHVCzpXCfNkyiFtRgxlUSmOc4/zR@dKam1MfO6T2ZKA7c9caFp/j4U9arBr/9rqNZ2bbBnVgxNS8rGp@1xHqMEhk@gvx5hnh4mW6hRZbmMvI2AHrFDtxKXAtFwF2e4wLVFfw1HsINL4wFJffhphEtldRqm1f4G@l@tAHC5nfl/dob5Zi9R7CSRq0Bzr04yu7g4WhSBzqvINRL0zXoNtywp4tRXTcHiz1X2wC/iBjeNDwLrZ2zYHtshO6ryNQzwEq8Ptyhg7T0tQtiYbew@41MshfUTGvUH3Qswe5Qk/R4bay1idOF@W@93xfCRdIKFW9Q0L56o9tqd5zpVw/U5yzuyqItpY5uJo25FzTxS4TU95Mz@rSgWGA04TLS3aQKlBKWeEDiysyxgmeC33mP/8OXccq0vpdx2hG6jRod5igWADH2OEq9t8lt8z63DrvJ5Rugc3fVYhQ5Z4NDOis6H6rSpmWUj8whZpKvb@I6g4mxsRYamgctb4wcJfyGiPj/ZFKecXY9OYFcCoCN8IEsd54luF7YY39NL6tFSY6mOzG3arMolAbgfY9QtP5GTieoeN2ip41GS3U6oJ1Zh2vJ1l/5Ddpu7OAHYZ8qBwq3KEpLejnrkG/tRYTt/BwOVolk0qlPAUmNL@z8LLOkkoHab8w@X0hY/KZ5zyPi3N6Tsi5PA8iS3jB40oRpK0y7ClysahYpmWMZ3h/T2nasu3Bh9QUCNWOiaoYaJa0sHddjd1Sd7wtK2w@dOHigEeru2rQgvc2nm0J9EGjeV2lhyeg3qs2JZxiHeL01@Lr@uGb0HTWXbngbnEcE@JLfQerdUlvNESVC3J@bavjGqrdMgY6f0xzmXXwinJ6LbxFoeFNDeNUMp9Ank/8R24IpdEMiGV2wErpG0ODXtdo@Xrni4nrP1ZGmtr4WxU8NYy2Mt032qsijEyQCxbeF2asQ8rS2LbAvhrjqkK0Uwa4btXzXSWB/TnGpUQ@HOo9gx@BsU5SzgcscO0ON@vmzuVDFyW@XqcNyebDy6tZAhrVmTFz/edSgE9mbajXyfDu4bYbjb@NY6Dv0dpXLZi93cVafbtv9Y0@X6UevK1qHMCPY35kyTrUAeteHxfOjUYLC@rD9BzYg8H70BNFIxeUtt1ditM@brXFfWIfBHemtyDAe9w5eKePuexAx8pW0zcm0C@59tgeGRK9rYo6wIEefl8lQ/0p8b/rCNJaOx8o4j//rvDvtC17uj0ejejRHA0mLt0oqUQ7pO/Sm7p8IQwtwbSdnvzGHrZkz1P2VsnQTPxyEdMyx@0@blHnnG307Fa7b96FdMvQx5Z5pvhDPvz1vWxXpIzJpIfoLQ9MIK8zk5FfKuHwE3wcrqp0b/SId2uBY42@smyEjjaBSyP9rO3y0VB0sRIOCIdaI98qXqLN9qXXE3M8BxpaORUM7/JpCXSswt1bq7FSs6IdGXMx7K3hWMmlpKSjQi4ZKVB41FXZLq6qCzWxdJrfViEULiVhFFoF8yHk9lYa0eigGRq3Bf8F/lpYIrW0k7P6k557W2Dy4foOqGh4Wz1sQSunQ0PW0GfplvdYRWZtoOCWSng2QeeaGGvnVLJrJ1UonjqQdNuERxMeUHWTlWNoA3Pk8juTuiun4ryVU2CL35wv5LSZLTemvYrpGF0@BYKuu1TEoU2TtKCDSG2c0McRdBTmXPHigsuyeyDUpQGbR/bjrlJbli5KWl79QZ8pffbU6Om4svuxOcaloUu4glh22WKmO2F/baK75tcmULJVzIbnQ/BpSCd8kAC@LYH3RO@Z7UcLFREg6RHYW1fKHwvsj1636@Kib7q4sCpwrBmYQpbjTIxc1wS7YUnMm@P2wdEY8wbEN10ujb1sbN0ezXBv2oxc64bVzTGNsnrPVabjqiVna5G4mAxHE9d7LMeBlm6FR6GHZ@TvXpgAXHoNopX19cF4@Uh1aMgVtDCvU5w7V2njn5sDu8c@L6QYKG2ghKFyvoRxHkD3/AzXBTnWEk6kvN9z2hMHOiSHF@w11K2RZpJpmeP1oznjMa4R8p9YGN5z4H4I5THe5fsfCkE6XU6Rx3fr@vON0Hf078B5J/bEaRvoDE43CZsFXq7Gnr/WGfeP2Hg6y0XYSmvbA2he4BgsbTJt25qMJWdire0Vcmt7hRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/eR4PcwOtDb9LCzXA@Ju4g9nctXLBwA0mMy1QxFbL0cXYvi3xkJ/KdEwLk@9Is4tHR7VJXD@0l9k7z2aOMX5vgwmE/2T40GjjtOGdeT@1n9iWDb3RCATl8NjgJwwsLPRYnhCTPcY99ECfzp3ZnBDYFZ0Q1zb0kdGC@h3MXe/TF3HAD/WxvqIrorFBsv8C1528Yg5ahvMFDfqF3KtM2kWEHhlTsi1WMwxvg9K43eYqMY7HLbSRhRkbd2TbFr@TtE3BQ32yXqpAV0C3958ol3HZ/8K4wFL7bLGoR@d8lYjR4UdgrCqrY7TsAb@vWZNkmXxNgO6Yhqs8xhMVyC@XYRJoX@5aGZJfK0PmphFosue6S5P0y02NOUh1@gFLgPq607ZxJsxzrFmdEzoG4Q4xHewk4AsHWkD4KUgsvT3xjnW8C63BsDWk20qDIVSbx0YL9yC16OyQsT69XZl8ZMg7OCG0ois4bsAXV9iocyz2DKyR@N3d1oIdtUhVc0Q3ktQrp8tpsY5kmUb7jY6jZjbRaz42vRAOZVaeknPFWHWoGdEosqLTvvqlLWlx6RooNANDGvcdsPmV8brhbf9QlyXzIZOhgZPMi7MwK1VX2@1TYe3l8@mBcHUMyTtZEGRJcMog1w@l3ZWaJ4KH/6MHX1WgE27mMv5BJyC67p7BB@QnjuU93ocDn9nuuGtOjwBv3IywSpxgsbKQBB68ZaBra1UhoPasyYCPPvRC666GHTLHJDoeV5IGJK7HhmRY5xIdOze9XSKbbzFTdvGc1bHRkbxTF3CmQXrs7zYLonnPJROoYdmIiz1VhRN2mst4yz@XEffClwygb9ljaeTSUxm5zw4fH53KI1dd2j/t9nGTxi09buEYB62QCg1JfaE7oflOvhytY7pj5cGJKu09PpQxwgp68xkNCR44M7fwWDnu6Z1qqiv6SisIQ43xcgXx0emTx4n5hlAW2@s79tCIh4P3Tk6SuOHlqydLg8OpD6B1dO3pyuSH@6oaX8K@zy2aHVwlPZfktArSqQHWKDDjI34KzJ3KVdseGZ3T2cj4FDpPlODue2afW1nIp/q52cNWyIorCUUNlRXlXCYeWpkNxrbhBM9V9XlmjlBatumh8MfK5SioOaQVJ71ce1g3439Ti2EpbyXChyVSU7e5dWxK0DJ6fXQpuvv3RUxV1VV0PtG7UK8su7KyFiMsmx8e2OfvMZVseMaLFHhJY@AqybxzHXleGoLoVvCGw/OeJzhbK5fBrAMQeOeWNvgLw5rplkRzWevUixKkxkVta6N8brzHhFSwwuccz5peOscXLKlnsTY543dkfOqEkuztPTi8K8GxR8v1sT5@@pw901088mR9xDDGxntgPNeMvpBw3ArP21s5ndpxAJS2Fl5vtLw9l9iJ7nRsaza9exKOdrxi105HGQew8I0iGQNzai7rq9p8XOvZ8mVGd@XNN3HYswU9OHwUjgfo3bf/haqmUnTQET7VFH@9o2b8Bs5i6NJneHpeOOj0MBANbdRbZPCIL7VGHxtTXI7CR4OXGfVL@7fcmr4vH1/dnawLK6wJy6zJ71YYerK0nFLXAMyuCWNZOQh@bA8u@ra8pzuGu2T98VKE1hWkuKYgxZB0flNI4SAoTSx67tUqPm5d8B5LufXUGDuZUd9umZmlZdjt4pGW7AkezX473FtOoTu0vKVne1s@@Pvy/C4mxtKMnuhvlgeQpDlbGgRC0OhPaEvE7eDFCdIW6LyG1TP5aY7sgT3ep7elSD6zccX60iwfmqOHk9FqREEk4ocEbkrxhYgvwFS2L1z2AHfEzbXzJSY/Lotb7r9KlWXBeCCeZfrodNdnqqMTRQvlOMfis2cL3rh1dXx0MvfjW/COJ1b4sGg36R33wXfO8r2Mruyf6B2LWYlEPL746Ynwzk2@ZxGPFOTbDSHu1RXb8HYVQkCw0dLby4gnj4GVY@AOYIFA4BbTmFWpqNki28EPQJRAh4lTjuhF5zv5edXY5qW3RbBUUq9xm6RYEpm3hTM4rpUfOQpw8bBEKBOTzlS2OYaQTX@DIaPT89kVI7sIFDE1m4I3WQnv@C57Oy8Bpc3LZ4fP9k9Od0@fn9RSjWsx7u0v5rhZFuTm70f/KN0Roewe2UDe8gOIaYfyALKjk/3RnnL9cjEo2Y2iVRaKNi@UuINpNi8tS1Foo60iXQN@kshzo1BQntCLw/ZLTPXj7ZMu8f2pAyKpuMlBi5Qn1FmJpZZlPNJBdmxaXvjND5NQKEunMZRn7J0ZCy2nZ9sdL0fXYHdffo4Hu4ePnx/vMx/BOdNcmJ1xv1LM8iOF@QZ@qKeuSct2KizqJYlCXVUq0YMoECYqR1mJtjfTcb7A5xDNpw5ujPZSb7HYJsEHCkaDSlH@6zeU66iMK1DjEDfqIxWFbIHliVE2NjbYKTAJe3h8@On@MUP89x@SN5IIQbBT3NT4pz/u8APx/SNO/G/0OENq8XSUhOBtWF6xXRlpTk13tPpLPXQAPe1MDk6@n3/9SKAPIwDfXtDpZDdOrorTYTL8s0vewWJ@RsRC/iHaONiJh4Q5Ljs3cVsyx6GLZ3YtMjuuj6Bz6mS2i58hglbBdPo6A6A@scb8XBzvFI0IcJociJwk2yRk@bccxFDE6PYGMHvLgD6AuRZYkMa4xL4ATsQBxRLfGy9J1eitJD5o/v0pqT8eDkIRbx3y5Sp1R3n3K/9M6ZUZuMfg/o7nnqYewNsveW9dcP8yd79UkNFuHwo2xyWMEB7k55WAIxLQH2kf@vqSxc8jmBMOzy7z5Sozh1BN50R1jM5z4HcJxPEcTqz2KVQasBvUmHcOAc/PcBoxPEmwpCjIUqiXyLT82pjytVA3ThTMZXMZVQEkpXMfIB0B3sNNnhxgPF6CZiKcm6PKK@j0tre3mYjGiVHJlXnNKpvWy7T4KkB0E@IKF31ErsYgDSSZp4CwqpcMOp@EGsekKL2iahQFV8eGXonCsffCd8sjhMhiQCxOIwPPlJ7iZ7jGzsw/GbOFn7YKfR5i0wMkqdAnkSsuCt7W@af2GNhn4dAAvnUe1wLyHhCPnHP5Z@boQErkR/l2y5rv@PS/Q@G1NRllAAeVTt3sTMN1K75AECcIoiQuY9/aS1Yf162GwnmTAZv@cAkzW@D@RaW3gmd5uXdvH0cYu3mYIBKL3T@xbLTCDqAwLKYpWlpRc/F5kTKZpUXySuRlA8XBw1CuIDsQUyAy2ob5hT1yd/f2D7969Ozk1pF7FDN6MxrI/ep2oi7JyVojcETDxVqskgcHysmTBwd@RcyRzoWkMQh@ryTqupLMB1cQ5Hyx/s2iLcPwZulWY/yCb@e9iW9aW4caJbqFh5r6gHxpwax0QNtebmauFZZRK5tdh9IcnhICvcf3LN5CNRa/vK41tqt1KxK9zQlLGsLLiLyFjQBcdXdrU0Fmv104LFjwOchT/A6VG26L6eVtUdxM48lPuGV6bJ/Nz7zyPEIBofL62YCIFGTFj7qy9R1xHX1@MpvGP1fJz4gKn4ATQjiXWkfxEKhT/8uXKEXm50p6Ryr2dbc/MFuCf/IQP1rRPwEuOFWRnxoUiwve1wl4xjHvW5jT0lSm1TGxOEo7gpVk605p9OHFBWjQqN09m4Cd9cwe8dOqaRb0oeG7jm0Qv2DckflksK9OhhCvS49jg0akQXJLkBgoGQ1Q5boUSAnvkMZpAo/BhPxqeFSjV3B52MnGpnG5b0w7Zg9keyyeBIn2kao2WHCQIxaaDm60oiLV2bwW1jbFj3EnapjsH3Sa53SOgF7TZTAKjWksehGNlxqQP/pHL16cR@PiMl6iU0W9YzY7N48XDdDPq@sliT72Wqd/ducyaVEs3pYS4HcTMD//yv9UTrEo912BPn1WQc39ZOw8BieoEbHuUB@x2MTiZ4fJjF5j9ZiVpEOVpCo/ftBiiQQZVPCgAJlRyi65eP8d060ZiykVYAL0da0OPt6YI1ZTZbkBbsokzjbxE1Z7oHHheTtxAWxgSFIisBVkITAzACPeSGTO4JAGwwU8BsmhE9iWBNMXfWjgzkaaUKlZ9R4LfZJsUXMUi8WSV6GLUrHIgPtui0NZAbC35Jyv1wN1vfM8gGZg/spCZC7Ib0u8COUb4Yg88g4CAXQioSND/fNBGMCaH@jZ7jv4i@1b0FbwSKPS89ODZiGuiCw4UKTnmB0cWOanXgcmnvedEmimykLUaJlbdB9jMjxBrslPLMGDzA6owYg3RGokTIabX/id86aqruV6L6FXCxAzgx2At/Gq6YPDoxL9Kf4lYcuF/c9@ht8QFmObqnrWdM4T0WyqDDe1nGVZ9tFmXZI2a6nK/U0drKjx62ldZLqS2Xp4bvS7rcOeUhdFlmYZRdmKHmw9M7Xcy9fT67RaeH02UnM1@fW0IRYqybMGe/bss7fNt3Fxej57LdZjdMIV2zu6EtUMmvmRUpFd7uTSkbMifnzS@2NvyFI/Y2/gOusy/Cf3m07IraO71cW4YlRkkXodvw0s5kVFqUUb8E9AXsHFDf9aVa7KO423b@M1XR9PZxnTNEdupwM/uw8apBY/0e6V7hGp0@nsPYXV7@ERqvdA9LMG/2h0hF@JRExinodU437l4bRLftNdo9eb7Osz7m9GJvg4GHtpn3z@4sULdLygi705jniwOUQ/j1JTz0aYltL@9Ccb18nLZ83tP/3mUDE28HGEj@9cP0H3iZr9aGPjowcPMpmkpmnc/ezzZ1/f3d3NPExmn9WyOxkptbH9J3@8saFp25qy0XBdtRGtnZ19JmqpjCj/6Y@izWfPvua61fT/8Y23VRVvebidszzICbjSTAUn3gvwU1HHYmRX3n1F3kSAy9XIjP6akSBgg6nVnfx/@97R68g4UtWUFw48x5HXkVwhwp3ggLe0/3YeqUa2MVruOjJTKpUKOPP/7d9D@upXAQ6GzLbhVs36sHKzSFWqUJKrSDUHDlXTIN//6xvfCGHIxUSF1Dj/us9qcImZvCbuNODaomtbwGPcpJSiWPd6NvRjYM@N@2PDVgv31HvoNg0bH5aB52sb43oEP@jKju4zdlxLJBINuSnBJb8k211VtToIALbAWjT2QlTyXrkPC/sFfOL5QNiLCPEUMBXxFXd7HsRq3OPFzXgvllzlF//Y17EQyW3cNx5WqyAK09X0VjVB10a9VOLkV1i@INr2fRASSRati1H2ij1m/LjPqpgqaGIymbzfxNcpklSaRuYEZJxGLLJA2Qibv7GwV4T5ydg8zofG28frz/7XP/v@n32P/r5Pv/@EJ95ZHbOrbEG6c2g6VX7BU6w64mWdXqDAqVKhVFCa1/XYFkiqxjFTUx9fRbPp6AmjJgd8Uo/746GR4KpW8Ub/3hu56HnDzwupBi8UY55kfTyfqBHogr21gVLtvNqQUHGqSDU1l21InB/9MlaLrHYfqknU8kWxUdWy2hFUnSryiutvusyOgAWZg0Q7cG3AH/3DFbxu4JjzBvlt@CEU6/a1EeR75wUwS@qWllayH@X2NSFSqykNowGKLKv6QO5vlDYKpVxJU5pr4LLybS/DMJ65kXNVbbdarTftlg5XS2/r6vi@nJcLsratT/SpPtPHrUlr2hq3J21VFSJvaxvsmDeDBkv4Vz1x5/Vclpuekxw2/iTJnkaEyD/CVVU1lW2BIE3BDbQHcoJxh39QDha5hKvxdqv2dgs4pJrYpubZqEoelvCQm/cbCen6ugbuctn7364GzjJd3AWFa1wnEtsvq5JUe1mtJQDkSw@kzGHKzWpjmwKCvLzMvOBoxo7m7PvbDQbZJrZr2xV7j36QEi6pAXC3F3C9fz8hg@s@AKhugiIRTyQ2JWkDZXjNk1UQuVFN@IVCHGLQKW4DA1xvX1eva9vX19vb8L9N92vvCb7X27f@6TG/VsSZhzdYLa0VAK9qtV5TqnWl7jFfA95lpYo@slIHRxWeEA86MyECzdMoCZEtthXBE7HSkS0h8urdl/8z/urvvvw97OkZ/AkRZQsNhCK3E@DG2BOLPeGXZcE//PxX9EGPJ1X0tPjNwjkERXklsxIfpo2phVxcRlnYtLtN3F0rs1cQlaGAYKJWyInNhDrTWGRbzOVJRPz8rSsajf6TV1oxH@X2NG4JfeW67pMQZj5uDP4gellLqZJ6VeXHL/MD8X9@2fVPfn7VJUSuikA3BnLPZZweQgQqISJJVSFS3R7iokEc0pbQejivfCY935XQ3NXHNGHR5qZc5XC/UixW@Wj85jPimq2HW3BX4X9/A8ohYOciRC7x1nqNf4/f4B87bePf8Wv8Y6dv8O94jH/sSQv/Tl/j324L/06H@PfgNf49GePf8x7@1X8unVbL4uYlkSKhFtXrzalIJClHdqr1n@PV1I3@9Lvf/Ga0UolKUTqTP6OC5a/Gy0BM142W70eFSIVtqptqapBqp9SW2gKHyVIOS/VTfbUDPVVTZSmDpWapGUsNbbUDLgP@UuAyU12W6rGUlbIgIoSCa9xMjdHVhUcP/roAyIE/E5e0tNRUm0FGA1Qi6WNeCB5cV826UANrWHxlgIYvq3JKzpkN/ARCTXz1qq5sNbRigcnII3Kz9qoebeBBuloxw1ozY6P@ikVcMBHKEaVeV/hgB5SVyHF93WzuP33YbCooP@tP7KP5/9HRMPy69n94ZD85soc2/B8dHT2BxldN3E@AaLl/vwKixnvsRKrlnXqJBJYvtCLK9k69mpbQnUuAHNLQL/GB1xwiPKsbdSF6EUPt7gIVvPKLi/J5mdwX/is4muV5BD8ad3hPuC5ANvuK3AVc5xfooDd0XryoBy7uUF5c1NHSAbsq@FeUhdd/gH/z/13/T56zOIvVGvHY5fV2jK44/sXjl9eX1969Go/FvJfYNvyhB7xjksvrKjop0iW4arF4I359zf3gHotvc4BVyGa7Smnn8UCGRIIsKVt@i/3DPiFr76pHy0yfL1Oo16epVLzc8k/4xkk3/YrmguNl@o7TZqumNv7kR3SO@06cImUz5bK6xfiLltHK5Yz/li@UywX/ZTMWK96@qqkdNQf6WiYTj5fL8LLjg03BawC2AGD9lyxANVy97UnBy8MjOuEcpEQ2gp8W4GIhlqLvI@CndqJiSbx3L@Z9wndnN37vnlZMXV0FPqMReKkLXs1mx3SaTfRPX12JTZFWDRSz8J4qXF2pqWJCjcZtJ/YUv9EEWcUklX2kVSnXIghfLZOPs3@QC4Blt7dzmWo1lwF3roDzl7cvogYTN6ORS7/vzse5aIxuKmKZm6LQul282OV1hKqdZbLxGAjXOOh/1xH8495qscj94yyTixUSRe@vshFnVVBG@B/a2@lEZiu/dR/UNPybLr1QJpcvjYp6Xbk0SjhueV1ue1/IxC29xr176SKQtZAq14Vm8@Hu6W6zWRFFEXtVuKEnSXcBP8w1cqI1qvJssVHDEjbq0WipfJ/YQy1kGfCBF0@KQjfBCkUihGB2cb8@lF5QvdGMDUGjJ96EojfGAZ4R7Nb5rwMX67AW6@HFesw0TWayAV1swHg43dvtIJLNLy80eKW0eAU@RnAJkWePd/f2T5PatsQi2sHuXlI7ef4gouJrdv5OwWl8P97ffXj0HBI8e7y/e7L/8eGn@8@fgb/LLuaXL@e9@/wZdi15v2AvhC@cN7ph6MbEMJoXk8nFa/aFaTZNqL/BBAph9xzmGk3AfaTPy1GGX9t09S@@0J0RXezdD7/97of/3bvf/u673/72u9/@/k@//P634fdj@H2XP7/774pZvP/0y3/xO@9@67fB8z/B7w/h95Offvnr3@A/ev8j@P2XkN8feb9QPP4TANYv/fTL7/3op1/@8g/g96@83w9u/37lJ8t/3//W6h@m@97vrI/z3X8Pv9/lsPy43/0t7ofPW/F/i8f75R@8@7X/wP//xPtD52@/@7U/wpv38s9/8Cf/5d03/6OmFf7k37771vfefeub7771nXff@qfau1//t2oqfPudd9///b/8g9/9yz/4H@n/x3T/3ff5f/eDf/7n/8uf/29//gfe7yfw@w/g@smf/0doG3/z@z/E/@/9/t/84Q/x/3/613/z@7/6N7/0b8jxG9zxf/@rf8fvf/Ur//mvf/M7f/mTb/z1r/7kr3/j9//yf//l//PX//Nf/fe/91f/7Jvo@Rs/@cs//KW/@Oa3/@Jb//Ivvvnlivu3196/fA//L/8RfN4fz/eB8z7l@lCfL/9O@Px9qDHPBfgEuPsX3/36LwCD/xpj7779Y1z/Dr8V/z/WVIrzY/72/wGHdrvMGJICF/x@9d23v4sk@h@ARPAf0Os7wctCCH/5zvwFyPqbSxL94k@//Jc/oreIUarSUDh21wWtkNgCk2arWPS6bG@UHJL8wiK0AICX03dQQi2EfQdl27sffuPdj/7pux/@xrsf/hJ2mFKmmNxNSuodUwwQMfse8TBi7n3iYcTPMP8EjQdJic/gjX3mBX722WdC80rBjRb3r8D3M/LiF@NBuBHDC/LD0B93ZrArFnZ7zpTn3PR8g5wJC8w1QYrGlq8FZdNsmvAQmuLAJT7BHyJNt8g5xTv5YvBUwNv8f@6cCiyBcfiF36XyneTw0nlZcKeQhWwS06lPLlLLGFeFtrgPTbpRvpkiwxJMp4kp2LvggBwSEPQgwSqVSgITVjg@8MpRqxYYoZJIVKDcmJqnSTYLCGL6gKBAykrimDW3KlOeMIHwqj45EgJ6HYuqJiYKlYeQYWX6kCEsBE5gX72qVAuVaRXBveX0SEwTDwgnBFZJTKtv4b1CMCGdEHn4FlApVBKJagEzxELy6kk2eSVlqXBU9gRLeHUATxzH3rnP2EeiWhCbXDtEgvHYeE/MY2NEiA7h9cSWVxz695302yKCb1BWXi6Mh@@QIrrDdVOMAHAlSZZlBj@cttth9yF4ykElKFt4JDiEBHEEcUDgwXDYJyEkqH4T9AL5RypbH3whMCzM5uamEKmKafFIJtIpCnPOSvy7Qlfc9CoxMVcU0dugVfU@LpC@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@qN@5u4kkisp8RQmTZrqST@aek03NVMLqlm842NjcGlhHnWqdoucUnYNbxeSliMr8DFhK8I7CvgBRfkgeu8mLfI7vCo7K10wgNhYny5k6hmoZnFhTpUNAcnjMJXeTQC/gazPvQTIhuffz5m1SoY09LhgRABedFn/nIfyezIfZkqujNxDArtMdYxPzXxG09yx3RHA30GjQfoEbm@vu4CpMMDplU1euUpOni/bpNPC9zXU12IWKVS5a2ayQsZrVR6m9Y0ATyELUWIqKKobAnpdFrAUV@hhN@Yx5OCK1pwCbiiWvpo@lGlIjFvpUeKVnlQCASw3thhKT8sz8O8t5xAb///teaiaZHtUTWdUreVETh1cGa2FR2cLXBmt5UWOE1wFrcVE5yTalpNbSuTqsCEbX5qG8NN4RVxbEzxkEjuJ1ZdY9CVcS9FRaQMNHHbOwW16qWr4qYUW@9UcOcwbiCIxS@FXuWCdrEJRqUn4wZ0x9IHQqfSsdv0UTuhI7fszkx2x7MBbj8Y2E4lCipZ1A8w8fvBuG@uYoBOgENOO@l0plRjDXlkj3YELZtP1NQUCHP8qYWkltwwdvL5UkduDwzd2cmWsoVkB3c2eJNCO9lUqSd/9uTxo/F4dGzQdoedTBES4OkteM7CTqGUzTZqNVFM1CibBn4wk4sKaWMDWpehdyR4dm1r7EpaoQGJO6ZTqUSjO2lVk9RSOlUQrgMKCUBbLGBVwJQJLFgS6XvpNcWSZVvQ7ktJPWleEhFK3W73eusyMX8R9EuJvwF5riU92boMXstSKF6JTZKSOQ8EH70LhL/0JsNKopYtiOVaef6ez4nlxrVwf2h0TB03OdRTl7dT5UA@cqgRyKjOhOuSY9vjUsvo2o4xj5hWc35EjtDtCBnxOsiunsIcL29nl8NIQENOOWBmfoxelRb21dRiprEPEqHW2PYP2EMmjrx8qevVKlTYZSavZbKZrJbO5bJ5DSR4MZPLFqBtpHKprKYBgEyxUMxfsxh0M7ouVStpLS1omqSlpbQqqWn8v8Oh4f/7x9fgX8M7pEprwinuUn8KXQN0ZxZ7jLtdxzY7tW368OMDo70ixl5fpyWQe47tun@POA9064wHPTT50XBB0CMdP/riDs1xf0WM56MhbnA3nH80CPvDFiBIYoIiPICbM7DtZRHy7PmzFaV8EhzGCsTgp7FC9OPDjx@dhp6n@7t7j4Qce3D09OGNR9aLlGWP9w9Og9c8D/WTZgMQX99//Pjmq/fIHD0/7k5sB3/CwdHzzPwWeOEOOyED12KkwJuAeDd8JeUJB8o3WDbvO1QB12XfAwPwnufM5ubOFDpf8O2DphusE@Y7SUvCqb@nUGcowVoGa/NzDNAipTOGPH1VzRcFYcQs@4LlU6xjDwY6fki3uwGefR33RxmotA3oO9CY9YXtDDoXZsfYEJ7gVqyiil8LRSSERwBkOGnTgR7Q0eOJdR38xC3OzLQGE4NN8PPSKzzhgV7odMxeHzqxC9uPILR0ndFKoA@7IL0RvsbrPcY8D/K7FTK4HV2ICKL4SB/rkUK5miqV7t1TnzlicSctuj2juj8FZmXPofHozixZyIpjWTxgcjPSM2tuYwT1lVM36qmzUsYeVXXQthOZGmin4267DH3jTiZbAvJWC6nsX/3mj//2j3@VFYpar6LWo9CBgs5MKpvZ3VAFmdR3rVjIFopprZAsFAuZrJrLZpOqlgTLJ18E5TelFtRcIVtUk4VMMQ08V4TQbDEvRPj6OtD8SAFUtkoA1mrjFyy3yQKQ@6Dq89k49iamx1lED94nTDQgjSigsTWm/aZbZgV6J6amWDrPAKLO2ixycLCXOjgQxQf4gqsQ9lKi2MGXbCGVyj8QRYNC9gqolog2T1PAs4DEMX9JpR7sieKEA8BjdEWxjy/7ORwuEkUTX/Z2Dw4wny6@aJgeop3xEP4y8F/yEM3CF9BgCcDrABpE2@X5ZAjRfXzBLDHkgIfsQZgofuyjgyHHPBoH8Mgv6e6uKB7yl91dDNmjYmc5op/gyy5doujAC7C/KPbA0XOg4YliC5zYCESxDa72TAc//FoonrRqjXVRnHHyIIFEcUqx9faZKDZ9f8zmUw@bLFK3RC8qL/V9eininyhqPtIYLR28pEUxE7xkoGyPHn2q98cdo8evmcOfbSjpo0dp3ZxO9g9aH3/c6vVazmx3/@NjDNrbewQKwmzitHotL2GrCZcNqfYeafrZcHbzglIfNpslfbA06JNmM6NbN4Kas6aBGEKq14CZd/Uwo2FzD4L2HjXv68tmRglgE9v/EJ4tvB4M4flAb/Eg/6Igek5bLbGM7I/6Nn1KHFoifdU7OdTbjl3G92llg7FoLJqc1XKpRpkC2BA061T5mr4hHsO7jsMb8ctZbVpJNSrTSl7jq2q6MbE@1bKmmNwY7qjFbGlD31G1TGJawt3udjfKopK6w2Lqva03LPY0vqOBai3Wd3YksaY2djS1UMrlX25NRDFewvtOOl@CiKloijG8xWv5xk4@G0qSzyd0RSvl8/HyNdBjDB16C4cdmrHYhaGfxeOILhrBUAT@BfMZldMsd2PT5LTC8WKzeHlaUcv8cEGWugWrgyfZTtpj2@EQewBuupMq0TfSRbVYECF/RYnF44FtqgjzNXwvvnZ6dnr6mYCSsOoZ58/4h3fL3uvHj/ZksNe9NzyBVj5Au8Z25D0UVwsh/IBU3@sUNHv5EfSgYOT4frinyLEH8v60bYzQOPID/HMFZe80OPn00QKck759wXPGLdllOlLIahsMD@g1O0yvVMGld1iMsGJ6/IL67ma1WmlWhvwz59Ug1SeMTq@dgzl0Oe7BRnFKfon7bLyAZiV1XW5VppEpwGlWmKS@GtqdV1qiXe7gubwPKg8wcbkJz1bZqBj4sXcxIpa7O1aFsYnl6l3jmeHgEQiHR5ugSeDmm1iXGfFNVqdPw@@h/n8tVR1mzTF7OhnGQCdvxRe9Qq9ImtjX/CJf0m4wXG1wXe5WWOxlvPwaXp1NFuvID@I7mXIn9oA14@CTetV91WUay2XK9MHMGEKCRkS0oU@uxyvVT0D54YDPSiVAxKvjM4CJOQFYs0MBenxkXpfblQGLSWzK4kSeTLlXqWHqK7xtS6LYkKTaVUOoStILoQrttDyL6BV30qLD3FmqpWqpXHkKfmo@U@5Dxeovp2WnMpo4RnkAr95IFd/0ppeBnEA1APPmKvbuF74R35ayFe5XJlBXA9A3mnKzMi1beDwUsEQlXYGARC2TSoJJDLd8Erp5LZdUc8l0MpOU8ugLfXwymwRPMG1AoYgNYiJjYjI1TclqUjXUZCz1yuy8iifPYqC0EMlYPDm29/FL8@ADlYRcSa/w1Fk8oW0NGNSCzfRtidgUJEUZCwY077ORmewjqGNDH1CKeFxi6a3YYDOGcTZPJ6P9WqNU2p@OvgZBMen1Ti6RTyXexOPl2Ea84hqvhWpZqKJUoVKPNoBnvUE85k6GNahjcKl5rVSrtbCI@VQynUpD6czmVW9brIqNZGojp0IVXaNIiKiMSwyuIs2VnLnfqIkq98CAqlOLWlmQaXAqXdCkopLdyqb4KBhPKYw8sYaUZLG66G/wjEWjeS0ajUfLOMS@IXpjqiDLSI5FQahG76k7IuhfYkksahhhLhJpD18qrIJdCziewDJFIXIpXF9eb4NBrNBKRNAb2Qa5JLl6X4iUGFMEVvfOlFE2GPvQBY6J7epL/qzjmmyAK9BBjqB80sIjw0QjjH2K@5V3WBQQ051hTdPSjZqWh54MpKMfFUzxMk4rRHDVt1wFEruXgN92oorHbHzCZjM9Eex2usdYL7EpUKEjN6cOdyu7veNdf1nV7h4OnNZByxbLUTFyGY1Er@FPiNyn/UUa31/EIqEdRnzo/Oei9yPRaBTHqIFQbyMkJNjepT@wVcLvCsX0EhcJtUb87VNzcFlIS3xoAmTU9XVkU6Gq8fdrfPJKA66IWLbvAdYQDgFBb5XN4vhvRHk1cj/XCuknh0fWQ@fAYHz7RiHTFKsRllIl3A5RLnm@WbG5caYCU6TF9Fkywu5HaAm3WCxoosY9yhF2JkXVEt/yMTopvsy/LLx88vzo@dGBEKlvXG3YONTPgmVob62vfg0iRtOZKGP1SmRayZS9RWjVqqRua3iMU56VQN531ZyUuqpyvq5SQE6DkHe/8IPMdLsA71pKhXdNyya0alXd0lg8Mnr35e/hiRyX@5/uPmZRV5@xv/3jH2n5v/3jf00Lu6LXZZfGpfMRiIlONZePXF6OLi@v4eJh2UgjwpHK5OPg5hMYaqSqqFrasqwyKym6vpVPZLT7Vlnx4qp5NR5xpYg3FZPPRtwrL0hLFSDInyshLzGHVRLZPzazmnp/G7lFDXajseBv23CLESFSePLqijF4aVc7vZ6pkUtRWOmtxLbfStvsLU5PvJU22KtKFae3VQgMBu@3cK8OTmFFqwllK8rA/GHV2nW5kWA0/g@m4kvD2LLqN3i9vsGKxRteWxb8GVsu/WEi38OFV//N2PrCFWNbcUXpdLzTnrYNlq0CK2wpgFk9/u4Xfl3Tcn/7x79y1bxqfqaBdVgs5lQt8jP1Zz@DCGvOUfBNO5rmwAMP0BGYhGzFB@jltihEJhbqwDy@byCiSYgahNmzwLDHN@EctR6qpSY/yqsTo2hbuM06STo0HZ0TLwtCoGuSjuz02kmCwbbw@yDQbIVL4SsYBF0rq4BIFb4yBwUeQ@hM7XbTHUycEe2aiFE6tZFk9yAJ5PAVPCVtg7aHe3JZAlGmbN1OylF2iWqkIbGh4bp45hp0KcJXIIl3liN@9lzHkwwwpmlBRyBjFMKTAjo1yLsBeQ94gib5xqj0PEKScex4Igv0aOEroBoQFUzQGJi5DRHKIHO@AgSAMsQ8wGaDbbN0nF2aiUR5fqDbNS4YxzPydH8XtYDJEFoHd@37icsYD7xAf8evhyFfeDUMylrI0wfCYfBJ5wpYAJic3lAFo2MO3hsUwKIjhWJUNHbv3hyrSsXsxBmVCOGfmSMcvqJ6sJbjCsB86@mjTklMMjwqr@z7BmwHFE8QusB1Ej8jrxxKykR8vRYE@H9vpkWOvFFVFFDGAnj1xVtFG0gGiZHsvA7bbLvCVC0fZwHybcC9TUjR8WyBSViffiRrn/mB14DhzyL@2fwgiE7DQ4Ie397cRs@gR5zgweh4mBIXBt72d35cEgq0w7GfOkgFRTEHFLtrOmCu0Gy4f1JbLK3GMdn8ZDvCg5aBaxlcQK1l4/igVBibwVPHE8e8fDbopJS2DRXqjmyLjiijI1RwpTtwBMgo73QnjvbEusAPaXh1Q4nDGLl0shNyPmJMR67RF0gpLU5HtxywaX3aJJnRk1l72GFakcWI0egUKisAF6dEhHALdF@kcWtgDAGlE8OgbUxuSVF6oDlNWnQU1xMT@Kp/YEKvYrmK97FX5cI8M5VTPAhcsru424kfbBBBZQubH5/59o69Gtj2GRuYZwYf6Y0tHAvhMtD@QYFNAmXnPyBsCZdUaOkkS0FwkseCXx4eee4sJENpN2Kz@O1nWt2INbFGr6iTMR38kOu5boXoS9eV4Bm87sz1D5ah41HgXQ5EruEdKVGJ4mbx4KwUwTsip0Kns8g4gzCKgfnpHy2DTmHkGOcMTVcB@xgQmm3/kAZsxVDar1AHQG0PWhaeODd2Sni0CGDidGJtaHqegLfYRyytCRiRn/vjndEDMLDqK4vQIQySYjnccQcqRqZhc5Qr0DqHHQjDTe0e@2F6n7vRTacBztmbbXjgsNOhvCqMNwv/JRt6wdaB/ExF34DAHGC4BJONmJgAsAkxLnLQQfqbyTm3CyRLSuw2pCRDCB6pAQqpCv6XnlnoixcCBDzQXX4ssnce3cXFhUyHJE4cUzZc/AqEi5@vVkY9E9RlWxkbw5H3vT0Tv7PqwZ27JP7xF/yo@c6UPidevDfjT0HouhVvYUos2nWj2Dme40cOekM6UAlPMnKJoQ5M@kBKO@atk@H8pzWSlz7/lZD/pEL0GoEwhmCmyVmynQRgyVb7LNm96JS9gHNqkAAcatHwPfHoUsd/Gbq@yxx1gxj2GOVoENQanNF0KkAS@QDtPGteQj/mzH/13kfmFBJZxgXbdRx9FqPwOMZGBo7NSO1hM@j2KQSc0M2wS36OpjmtzRoLyadBcujUfGuIOXhaknC5Hig/VBXDpzx8CuFTHj6dZ@pnW5s2uEqGXtdYHOR6PGTPj4lgZn6ca34A6TyEIIOOzVQOAmPOFvyu4deuUGqf3vwN6rHiMwbwxAgIbsSU2st6rd6wXONiq5FQesDsIhECahxA1xpE04tO4EbqD84HI9td8LLwbEXolTy80avd97iB8wqWMaggYgxOLxOPw@sNvWUIXCHwCgwQUA@DQFQNdscxM14ODvGlQGCcmjinMUes5iHTIO3LC/L8QF3ipOeEDQNqhAChf1AkQBNCmN9y@Dd/fOnwwrEhjh9Xos@UDPFYpmgjCpS80VS4rClTJYWwkiQfTSA7qquVm0Xxw6EqajeCQsW89uo/jP7GB6PfhXaxHHtiWN5hlIVwU8FVeKBCeM2FqMqqlVC9AgbKlj4wHOi59rl@6vXWkM2W4psZPB8sgnuBHzKOhSq/Hef1Qzv9REssBawwq1SgiLMKb5a8Xfgk5QQPkrlespnPCF56LkAARmppMsNLNg0nm1YqXHCw6YpkFyEkp4TklCfhsacrkGx4ycB6OvS7F6yeBminuExQBHgq70ZBDRqJDL9mjJPaX@CRcWBV@XnOZQ5xgcdDqGIjn7UbS3OvhZAOCa0bAJARbwHo8M8HloSbAk@VgrdARnFS@jKKv3lswGUFMBiJ4DI/VjUWMBnZwKDwiwnqB6DtiomaIKo0yot/Kf4Tk76n/1Nve6YWY6qLnqnkjb9/FM8GUjbUQEPah5rKoEBGS@a55Z1HGNY5Ivil3b4NWl3rwmaxJco2@CsTL6nSGtgtZajj4hT8qJj3oe3RLO7bDzhDwu6P7LE@tjOZEjeaTGK7Zflzm8HsWTZ@iyB0tDLoeh3bcK3oGCq1bfcs0zWSDE@9OzM8s8PwDqcXwnqy57RdQfCGJ7kZi6A5X6Gq22ziZ06bzRgu34uXguXCtJoP2TMaFdD@BVcoPYgnD@jRKGa3vjDa4/jdMPGccC/Zqdk@ix2NvEAcSt1lIMPaoP9DaB80GObac8uRziBGVbo1jtGB/H17aPdA65u4soCpb4A/nMNGhPTRiHBJMh1N2lLotHhqJbF2Uo97ST/54KTsEy2mx4P02iKABWIkmXOTxkhZZ0l2zZXZ8WR@ficfju9JGN@T9fiSFX4TZ26aV3jgh2Wdjs0hQMQ5Gum70cCig9zq3EJnAZXAG/UqnuC9UezQ4q8OYroLUXe96HIX@CMZvLnwFiD@6Sr6r69AP/n@@1afjt9@PpmBvBniosYYfT7G9ac6YxD9MB4XIkuyC1j74XvmBXHxy10HqEKAGkuCy8LjU6FhjsDsdoNPAPiA7@B5XG91i@9pEVaFBy7ByTlPsjNtdRU9bHaMgT4zOjEvZjIE1y/xMRhsJK/er@Ao6Ejo2dzWi0HfFQ9CoRtHovNIpRUsoyfP4/HVbMWjmAH30Eg5YXi4mn4Yfks04xBfhY9Wgx0QjUZwOPbcxOHP0Ww04yd0D/hHRDw5yvsfXpN4nMHdBAE68N5TTc6zja8Tn8exoEjv0SMEceXFIuMBuj5EPKzndh1@GInuLilUbihRxa9lYfHbFMtr3FxX4yGu8HmSTyG9H0vexXTvzXMhVuPA5iJs78O6kFuQcXVGux0LQ@Q@a2vMtm7JBPSjcTprRa/SXCJQg5Qk6cYmmdukX8QFtIwP4YkDTp/CEwH2jHGTM5RfNhzT8j7HxShkqI9CWovnA0o6QAlRkZPcQyMUS/DdEP3yOsizvTLP9q082wt5Bi1gMctQJKG9kKVXC1g966pgYHTHK6QzBqHtDI91Yhsuy9YdHK24jJrRkplk0fNoCQRy1IiW9mMglKOdaOkhOdxo6YQcZ9HSJ@CYt63oVbTkNwuM4MArOe6jvyfC8b0dLe3F4tfCWD8zXD9fOVoK6hTi7PBXogiQAssNWiNOsVm2V8yxY0DHRkplkiHHuEk0n2gcJkm/FPzzr83QdygwEMc4tygySzB1odMI9Rg8H@g2/HPOl7Tkkteb7x8d0OqmIApmkwAbL5yGwIMaHokuCiOOGIbSjAY8AUGUm6XlGLFQT/ae6Hi5A4dSJS/mT9STSR/oxCi8BpEb80zoE0Neer@@FkHwCnw/PDHxKjxvoeNnRxjhnGx8CVpI1FfRNYXCul7Exav9cA3RWPdiJPx4uh@F1xKBDcl00OFocg4zG9mjRSahUFxCb4bT0KAcb5TIvTeSkVTwWuaKYPL2SoaCIdz44@uKE0qHqC2IIAyspRq8lQX9AsliDJrLupCmyhsfoBCSOdDCjfYZfb7poeekeFzcJKmvWNUN@Wl5liS5FsUkJJbxfKiJPua5B8brPp4a9WHmq59yimMtMQQQShnkwuWr/QH6u831d1@h9olwI4NlivXyrvS2er22l72B@WCe7e0KxMAkexhfqhwFOcxJDtZBSDNfx2u3VHxc8sGVfJ5pAP2Gtu@TLbAJ7qDbTduCw0ItwTlf9DzTwPNMW02o2xrJ4Fz2lRYZc/Lg8IIHmM6Lth5XXvBlVYwhNL6tDz64gp3FCg5XHsKjAjg3SM5buTOxaJXLvG2D2OY@KFLVEuOCnKZLg2qee4K4p6nbYNoWPI6axw@Pnj7@OnS6@Xw@7vXRszl@2GpxrDXoxzlkWiod9AdLzBYtid9YwcluHI53@7Yz3qhb4i1ZwoU1KAM65OKzn9fG454sC8nzG20X0vG4IYp6sM7mzUBfkEqo6ujYZZseXcdAEGMc29I9IL56C/ROkrUWp6@JNJv4cfpmk7qvZhMXLzWbXi@GVePPiMd/FtlQJq5Dn/Pkn8K5EAQ6CIE9PGIvHu2estNH@@zg@d4n7OtHz9mL3aenuAf@2fMHjw/3GPz2n57sM2FhCSV@NgwNSqDrQ6Nt4LcgmZZKZRhB3rNHMy53Yntx7n@iD9kju23gNNW2qw/v9/mLbBnjKk@1D@boDMcwTfpM3NAc43oL@q4ZmLGo3HRo2x@u7GcQtwU27RBt3qHdMbsmxBXQ9h2ZhuvvFGMDE2oQ5K2/iTjJlST8hBktHaJPE@IKrAtIrkN8nLsBMDpff4Ukxhj8m2cdmXmEC64PpuDp/vGTE4bHKewdPX14eHp49PSEHRwdw@uzrx8@/RjoeXhyenz44DkGUcQnRw8PDw73dsmDI5CSGZ5z8MXEHa9FQcboRJX2Gc58yyOo/uDt/ynuabfa2JH8TT@FaJPQDe0vEgjBmMSASTxLIMNHcnOAOI3dNn2vsX3dBuwE7pndH/sCu//3EfZV5h3m1z7FbH1IanXbEDKZcybnBHe3pFKpVCpJpapSUuuNK3hx45MDZCTmr7oofUK/E34NmvMl6yrC5Qs6XdJRgXDmKgdvPsCcL4Lf8YRTHQWT/YF9HNG1enMFsU61wWDZgPFWslTgQidbdOk84nIs8GaNoETxDxx69oQCTkY8zTAQ9hbaqKDum8Mk0FhWoKGiWYCNoJTBSlnQjTjz8946gdyA2hqdHka05NrYiFC@YNHXytSkZBHFpK0MAkXvhVoX9UHFkv4AfA8flmS1wwFnEM/0B84gnvMHXIrW0HZELMscV8P9KxTPYoU//HrZ36FjYfFCf9j0aRe7KnHifqMu9YW@UQyDRnTo3iPW8tDdjH7UCEMqElF@vBOo0@GBEfBtdCAT@SiRbNsgpw3CpoVHDdLsjS95xVTgBrQT8lvDSDhlNyeO0Dgo6IZ841S743fZBCo23SHeE6sYn6e8IZcP@qYm8gfp94gB8Za4JB663LZcFQaPLQclNydq9KWNJN2WqEzQvofA5gQC/wgYAJS4fcNv0ExFPqkIpteSrOxEPeBI1Nv@YeYHdm5eNYJEAWm15fwafv3qSiJ7iX2SslMk7KCLvgYDWFbSUWarN4AxTmKV7rZBKdi46PWHIfehk2wBnTjRNAe5cWKD2r4o4srakA7pGru9rlHpOXDxPbWeA1M@plbieD471@IrvvQUOB8mYba7Q3T88951YJydeXiIdBOg@gUWwnRWjsrP8ZAw4fWnFcuOPwTelbha3tjePM3@8cXDCxNZLPB9pcroEP8DY2JdMDzonI8MFge47pIjTV10FV2dY2lpgyelJY5yBQz2gRch7Ote10s6jc2NJ7@jx0z6O328vS1zqSxKJnnJbXThxNLNEyeqSo/KnAlpAmLITkAWZL2jvngEU8vr1@glg71QAop0UY7gvj11jZQUIap151ctkCzyNk/Z3Rq@KzbIoiK@Chm9X8z@yH92NsuLG24@NigRBjkdJaI9BbnouoZZCs1XE@C2HwYH8vvx4FYfxI6nhx@Ctv0gtB/CLbt4PyyelgxYjwf7xwNgeXL7h8BC2737AfMkOQlNc7pmTm8uo61pH67xy0Tf0dgDMDj3ogZFAzVqu@rSEbUKIO1wAdcEEy@IDo@2qwcHwub9CZQFuYdbhqYUgwh7VryPrW3DLgm7nF40mVGfefGkviQs2tS/hwbzVOLdIyrkGsST9NDCIr70uxWOWOrJmYWWEGR9TwJRUS6J3Tclg6ITCfgO9oCAbNxpRgOtqc3M8OQTRqYRuKSbx2tj04afLKx57sY7MgdjE5BpE@S30bNkev995PXxmqqHF1gYGQgb3ISVNMw3sE84hIr7kDGXS/bgA92iuhSN7HmBnVG0Q8OvQnKF/fMMRYzEi3BeCxtiXS6OJWq8Pp5TyxwySMRpwEdLT5nIFs2QoEQ8fVk3O9SNJz0nOQXBIhNvTXxtcgUUP7uTUxhRQ8@TZb0gN8faHGFzorA8Q@2shF26P9MTtIVeSYuHdFUgbR@sKvvPqYpniURNiuZTG6MSAfLK8vKz78FOt0IVz/4sbJ5D0vJzeNmH/X0MMhpHpN4Hzq3teSo9ZoAHSMem9WrApArCUmfKnJJoO01GJn6AC@uFABkMp44XUaZrdcUohdt06DwjmdApy0QbjCGsG8qjZoL6dw9XhwL5u/XN/nh9PNgwE5oO3qFV/rveIApirzwjUovxCV1bk9@CwaBL2dif6RKhOOTG9KCzHXnbscErtwoT6bzNbElLeiex2a2ndA1UCakXc3j3LGr3Smn1XrZYMpu6U9utigUKs9hK6CLtge0asmc27D6EAMlg0kvg9EE@fE@iNfgPOHgKJJCJvPkcoo37XdyIIrBqPqHrdKRZqJStxXTvt6KG38UAH579JBK29xQKkha2ur/jTtOsF0qJ8oBc1O86UMqzszmbisI3VOgipCQI7k38bkxY6KmhLCXRvabdQ/soPNgKRqw9I8tJP19cLay8tKh1XW/oXZ68PPMWGmVbwOTrdy@jq8FN87d27@K6JTqi/@v5qDH@@rsQy8/FM6hr6SnHui2ulPMUXvQF/F0VLwvEuRLBVxS399QWIse3FAoxL@J9eGlW8EUdtGleQw@JFJeKhUvFhehiNyxfnqyclbvlQunypHtWQie/4WJ5uFhcdPDDU5hFQcbwyfzJ8AznVFPrGnSvBV5eS5cMStcQQa4h8OWdPwh7u5W9NwltHC4AUAUmbb1Joc73zs6gNRv6nuS6wY0j1WSeQI61cIFkzZBXUBH93kmfjOqYZgiYQa94sJqNRvR37FozhdxVf9ijFBWzEFlL3Ia31oxyYyqQRgGynIQqsiH6FwCcOI@DB0P8dcxW1NkiL9eK6DvpGiBOsCSJQ/vUttGnEBGVvlwnZ1aUC/zGBSKBFy3fUjGxvk7XLgOrRTnS4qEphz8gh4nCGT7iAQj89Om0AauglXtEbh8WNB/fi/jAX0hHNSQ/GTKQt2iliClo/i2@kX8TlV8HAjDhZ3jNlZMqTrnygoUk@w6ScgEDlyU3/njMgG6V3Ckz2FiEzfWVY@BkKU40wmolmeD7zA2Sk2kF/2QLskV6m2iGzu9ydiIJnVPLtwhpSV1KSRv404mLOUaxrCqmMhukmPkuNVDTBdujdwEMq7HYCjodQJppMROTAx/Jv1fWv6jrj06wzjONPKdnJ9KzifQcpzNSca4cTPBxpjUzk535Fue7E3aczZuoqyxo8ZKDnm7kYEkS5y09lDfKDXv1MM68obuSuVInrCcSskbK5ym9zymziTKawXX6CadL/l6SPa@xTOR9nawffy3ZQQEZz0pbkxSX5rph55Ul7@iVKchmNlBTCC5OV/oJNajK0gdTihNYwaGen4btRjmGslhUEofGjL2x/trOyUXGKyeNBnsxTgysKWPEoBLVuUiEG5HDItRDybMGCIKJjCbUyN1Qhcey8NgAi7lmVbXsBTkxwKFp6SFeRr/IW/yjBnsSOZUvMz1xhjEfcePZuzlJIBK6s/Z0MiWlCbqL8EfZqAdmkbjucRridCGxZ2iBdZ0B@2C3UA0@q@WEKSiUpJigu06RlI4zFBX73teFmHhn/T2/YL3xYY3d7wQjUcFthk9eWFbCwX0YRMMIIz1RvJroqt/v4KkjLfhuyIVaxgxZWsbjlhiiMbPnrBpa9nB@D5@kQzoUyol9hHyDBiJxQnTVbqMzGXrA9m5QtKLGJRzmrEp3zAoNGDPPltjNPBBXEZ@awm6/bSLBPcejBykd9f1GkLNgjRbB6sfiprZCeRUm6dPRbwRjicGUtmZZf74KG79tvcHz3BfFwrOiQbJreRxcyD17HjtYAZFUwhLGAVwuPrcs42y4wWfDWQToiV2c6D8AbwbXQbcbWBWYMShjBIvWKBhcB82cZR0E@hAY4SIr48kk@mH3rgYNVu7AossHZkQv4cjj4zDgMPzF@ZmPixt0VuZZeGgVnzZDV1@HTSSg8jhp9fB0mA4sMEwA0wMLXQZDIMqCK5Io0dmzxIXWLpeoiAJqYJwT42xCk6HbG4YN6BnSZFkdAMXHIHFl3WYKE6iv0fHROTg3DQF0j4kpoBBQR0kP4WDJQ/MfwkHIhqkzdl/1TB6kX4/GCgz3YBCC9I0JTL1CxQzcoYOP3tYOxeH@ztHHykFVwPP7g/0Pte3qttj8RGfceFBOUXXF2/1dkC76NJ1Pzffhg105hJI2JViVvU@i@sv7g@rhodg/ELV373drAA3AH1T2jmrVQ0/U9rZ2j7fp9B0giL39I7Fbe1c7gmxH@x7VqopZcTmxvyPeVQ@23sJrZbO2Wzv6RDXu1I72sDI81a@I95WDo9rW8W7lQLw/Pni/f1gV2DBru3a4tVupvatu56B@qFNUP1T3jsTh28rubqqh@x/3qgeCjASMVm5WAcvKJmxhsSZq53btoLp1hA2Kn7aAeIDgricO31e3avhQ/aUKzakcfPIk0MPqn48hEySK7cq7yhtonOV8hyrQL1vHB1UMhYSUODzePDyqHR0fVcWb/f1tovVh9eBDbat6WBLW7v4hEez4sOoJvO2PqgYYQC1Ih@fN48Ma0a22dwRzxvF7tHdwoZM/AmEAywoU3SYCoxkEthaItH/wCaEiHagDPPHxbRW@HyBNiVoVpAJaVGwdmdmgQiDikdlMsVd9s1t7U93bqmLyPoL5WDusutBhtUPMUEODjE/AOlDpMbUa@wnw4kdgVktxrkfdKWo7orL9oYaYy9zAAYc1yS1Etq23kuY5DLVrKFHCHuoM/EtTsdKa/HQdYKjJSY3MdB2Njpi0tb9dhRlZxq2y44RjmHVWU6GUzDSYaXQivCZC1jSD86t2Pey2euhjqoux4uMyant4sY2Lt4KcWg/c6yT1K1Qgk6nXP1TqsNE9rNdd7zElE2h8r4RUgz@Uy5VtxCsLcOeNip@1Nab7eoJQG0/lQScZ6uEBBOZk6j9l0zf/MnBFPt8MZDF03kfASnUU8bHJBR6lgGgkZ0e8ziSukjQT9B5KdqCCjgKfa9RRT4qWkZSpF8Gf7m38wpOD8QGkM6u78nncxBIa4ddAVcOVUEgE@iMjEoQtqjIXBcFvbadgVod7/ly712s6rqvKUN4h7APbjvud4udBO1U8my5PyNKxs7wGIFL7blrC6PNnSTIh@yU3oJY5@Kc@pB9XYcMxH1BrSlWRsloqLZ2nXBwtkjwhQ1ugewV1Mq753lV@qX3E3Vxh6Xkp9f2t/s5jC@0FMSQtTHgnVO6Mft6ecQYYYBSLA0gSyggZ@bxRRtmb6Mw3kPECM92ETbT8gbn6IqB5HUgCC9krv2PWibPxIByZ2IMcfnNQebd5vLMDohOxfb66/GKlZOmwW794/PsJ66G4sRR1rA/zOKzTKMkYJVuw8KGRYsTrjtmfGDifx4wYjV11Gn3EOA/abiNpyYSCDJsb4d0@XTTRswOkgy0oAMespfh16siUDOAkmupiay79ES3xfVgrEQ9IY5bOmHpthH8Qth7@aojrBkkGkixGkXSBc2F3QXLP3lGmorS5ocA9mCVnKz7mMG6aBqTqIvtZ9K6lN8nbRi9GbMqI45W6nUoCErNpLISyq@jyyH5PcUakApiih8GXXyS/weMnGeCOwt350bAyPAQy7uiSqKeOldGy0ScS8hnejIFB1VRN6wK1/K5EisaeVCfrwCDGaCBU8AoVtPFNAi7pOCLpKskC9vW8K74xp2LwDoRTkhwr34FzpzVHQimp@CHyXUWlEAxLBzlhqt3oOiyV5ZOOY6HImSDTT9GD4P8LaTIF/jrsOAF6TC0jCOCjKElQmVawfSWihDfqoME43YipaX76FIO5MzvmQjdMnt6M2L8GSCB7Z6w@fKKwhy1nCgGQyVGxYY5fbZJ24cPW6bXtyuJ4TtJtXPYdIecKNVVMwM2unHm07PLU2Qq@uMJlXZNR4S4UFa9543ZOox62TKmtvHgS2QzOVfE/8gukANEDnrj0gq1W05xVkKNMyQEZasmYcJo6YhIsS@/uPbVbEEaIzITslydfilAAegPxmWwnXRPSE2yem4y4SDOxOKIoeBgdHLfJOPnIkHXnZIjZCRDOkyYpQ/AmkeENThAdhk6h@mJownlChiJYSWx1GMcZRHHr5oC0NK3eaOxJM4kcqrE/7nJY@oC1WipHjgN8SAxNd/mceOePAeXO45rNLJZfOOx5aLuIlbFaQpbHW1Mavd4Alo4@thtw9MKxmxMfpdIh6EZXAxm/EOazcCA1EmrRD9Xgsol37zTNcER4Qi0Kh@it0MwRf1CTLgO0EOXwJKPsinCAeRWPbiilYzhaLApnPU5ZB5pQWFIi4rpYEbe3nIsJKkOGBkTBMNKbC7LZpHrw3EEPv5ve4Dec@3EJ1G0GTR2Z1ABJukDupFqXYjw2htz0fi8ijQZ0BWpANCWKrEjThqowR7@Q7CTtmuw4OibGLqWW/Hg9mkmVtRRUFDOurB2YbyULnYlUWpKhQXWw0OLSMqEybcN1d@9mjKKFJo@thX3a1SJljRcR5Sdq6YhPLDf10yd8kkr@8pMIRw98wTNuuQRFhHHNiueqk3KO8EObgo9hMGiaOlFYyTT9PqrfaOvT6xIvKtWhDPvX8IdRMIYdQCMfjvIEo@78qXfRrW/1On477IU@7NMwqPuIJR4@jukRO6w96N1EdCEQJTSNTM1x/MzxZTgMG77rc8mSEZorGgZ9xzRTGA7GlQsOE0GaczQCjC/cJP7up2Ok6TLPl@NCVtL/lOzxim7p3rLPitMK84k@ApACbiNlQcE@pENyTDKcT0sTGc4fymDgeC6ywnfvsdhLYPwSSETHMAmMFTITZglmI3Bndi/GJ82R16QYhAMMtBRsB3ixTeTQZ8/HO4xBirxCS4E1UVwtGEX5FGWEcQjxYXw/uZde/IuxBwR@Av3is2ncMo0RSMS1VLSliPcrMsoo4ELmgSHJaJLEIMXCdtg13A/pSolRGmoyeXwfNcjyBxZFMszeBFfiiHRg44P31jl1EDn1sYuTyryYdyluBy5BKkOncD/DBt@zn6XBj4e4rDlDwbQlITsG0veRqgFUwltiU@a1JsocU/n7I2Zp6bG9liJgeZrJmXFbsWOrlQt5oIQ8v@KxVm8AwthOUU@aesxHw15//pHUu1d2TI3MNo3WDdf9riEwM1sZJsuFJpG2PMbHcclK45NimiTFyNIMeAi3r/Ss2TxNxFG5juOtXB9/hw730Sy2m9KTiu7vJo99nBSv0aJXTTR6SBHuGKS0pL@f1KHh9fsliITJ26s6SYw6ioz6mB8NUCkyaSo9nkLEfRL3FD2aQDmstwm0M/vnXqKmjeRUyFOVlAhyifTEwO3otAlyqd9C4wsME8crXC2k9IJz5I3pKK@YPccgw5jAAHFVHGRjPRRrcOPOSvER3Q7QcupoLVRESQRPG6aFgw76rwlGUfmlckdaPNTH2eJZiSGNNCTYVVCuhyApf3N4PamPCMoEKWCITyGFbtGEbLp4fKt@ti2QDyBwaUqWlr4FDxvjikXABv6YSfURroHjqmTJxIhKDoQ6iQYYC7BLaXcC3q7i6i8cMMejdYMcRrCB4M8O/izKEhjOe6WgqY1FRs0xZnEluXm0uSK7wUVihuJ3JL8cirzUpY0rAAgYYyhfLgIEDGtK2OOhAIXeMTkvgajsIyhYLuKwhI8UFTW285ySjkSVGZ4vGzkK03K8NGFkpwKBhcX0PDEisGaZniWGAhPdVFyMHC@mtyfOAQtixftMcegK2StJGuqeYwLSlcwFN5YoJ0XhFSQHU@LzZTeRqPmbUl8WjNRCOhXoozE8yRbTqauFRGqi2qWlZNFESaCHa9aaSARSuCbCWir83D9yTTFDnmubUGOTkVhlSPtsvDIbdpmwb8v9Gol1cspWawwFz/QMV9uvOl@xkgjK/nAAdjFPRwYYu/2nW6ssUxUm8q4AikunnF0c3hDSitXGqR6bhTtdFWlPByhQe9peS3w42tlJhH09HytDo8tgsFwoFJCJz83g98q2GlVJYS@fzJ1vXXU6@f7NnwYfzvMk@4OArgRYUzvoALoEBkWU6w3afDME4gBZMXdWOrLiXv@q1TKvYMATSuw86DbOKaMhCJqAQm308uGIFEAEUk6wX7CB2L4vQo@@G58XmhKKOoaC0mgSfG2r0zMgD35ooX22PqkiYCiYlTUTzFtueeMbziB4swl1FoUvdr/F5sn226DT6XniI14pjJECZu7SBXZ2zAIFzoInjOTdexVRPFpPBNdhx/ArxiwmryM4NTGpeyZUXHiMjX8QtKujvmOffLZhWoEmL2IzFzE@tSfstu3KYPGPAMt8CGg/Kvel33caRKd0Zpjq5QiOnwCjZ0Vv6t4nkcUlnZik2fdzI1Gno5ujYA3QdJfWAiqWPXUvteSe7Jq49umo2EIaFhiGxAljrjyuBLqa/evE4vWw1XqcVKRrALhjf0gi8k0oPycQ6QyARqAcfkBPjKL9b1kY1jupgCK8wMHLOiblDhaoYwHLetIo/37jVCoVMddfXBSVyiY8ZLOislkR2/hhc1Nsw/smvj8tLy0vl1jmbrvf4OOm@ngnNgEGaTgXGxeDbXiFtDL6jaG1NnbxXL4855Xm6uX1jVKUP6lsols/PP3t3//zb//xX/mKfPkffNmkl5PPOlMul8vPNb7NPb0r4fvJ9tn83PnJXP9svl1CLvs7RQ3v1YZZPzYfzQ3OrQzPAsZXsiNV@2yKPiOLCnXh36U/@A2ky5rINKJ8Rn6N@OYokrGZRmB8D9CP8hy28OrSgfRWHpDIANAxquOhdxoBGuDBfAOUBFzQDpTL89mKUtxjOBidQZ@qZGQkHlqzXgfo0xJHUkBfXJixsmE3CrqoAb@mNS83z7J8@A2Hdcm/@c/vovZmbyQWTh2xUBALnliwbfoprryEr@5cPkTvXM4G2wHb9iAlPlpAM0MRhbTQo/0D3bWTIrdlzdGVPQhJhamgzOwF5@ndHznL8IVrUduawYs1BatI6JAJi2S@zXXvoFu@QY47O@FqQwuFutzFUGXGiYruX1wC@REbAsQ1XzJB1npQJZ70kUcyPuXVF9nXFt0mRICRrAdvdmjc4weYi@a60uY5sZfCa47IfJ6/4txYYmdoQhtTuP4YATpQ4e1kgTwJ5zPzFlt5G62kZrIXttk@yXxs6zAOhso2nQv9IQwmYGtuk3BzXenXIg25@XhF2KE@XjGqstO238IyilxedYZhX7orUO04oL7p2u54JGGPEiCGwzH71yZHGCkKVKSoVLfwZVlj0exh03kkdKVrOnSwm@OTI4MI@c8OjO3b1Nh28@QlotiBeYCQ0qZ8LT/sRDLqyoCI3fYH53g7oN@iC9WGfG5G@jy8SjWFca@lkc4RZDI5j8czNCXTH/jtS98Tmb3e0cAf12DagpXPsJFzoYUYggmRwMEnq57WPIUwt0h2CVFEN4Ush/Dygs5YXo/GfWtrnxPsUjUUZNgVHAQJdiJKBreJvkrRMebqH@gEE@UJ4a1PI6WIJcmLlkYSkm26zdAwmxg6lqrBHDt64NgWo6pHpuIFWegKJ9pLOvgFSd7BGAGyblt6AUpXhJWXWD/OTu2g6ycmp37HUo7@@ZLgeRHHM11FydZIlroEtRjfeIdYwTryczIKBM9NKpyRNeM4M6eRvM4tY84jFORb2@LnfRHqC@joAjPyDBHH3ZCFZWqGiu/AyIkaWf4DhFbHbwN@4xt/jKx4mnFezebdk8@n3bMF57R7e/rVJUykSFazbFZk5GG2klhyrMDMmPcSr8oqLVKhBk@7yQynXcE@LAYJAJG8c/I5f3abB4ROM3jD/GmGCZLoMsQk/3B9eQSfn0Azk8Qin7Fm3AVXdb7zqugKmFvpF/uQP7j8C1ioTSWp6WGfM2gBKPLT/f2KXU6i/OpS4flS8TnshNrBKDsIrnC@zUZX58EIlhIRbmdh6jn9muCGBCHuRpFfgo8jaCdfa8K@J5F0UpIiVA5zqsfSbAVlcswTkB@oTOFS0cXF1Xl8PHzEDb8ngOVUXooFxaaDBvc5OH9GvUusx49QrqW9Q5gj0cqAbURIhZpFyOrylfs41FXDZZ78nHJiC2O3EhDo3nzGmC26vW5WLtbc3HwJF9HoNdNZLawW0mN0YogmRuicXEzNz4rixqsXf/3v/d8zw8zGUv7jAH6Hmd8zK6sZfoQHeHum3q4zG5l1zLZylxnnYQ8Mjy/@@r9QfuNPAAdTxuvwZ2NZwVoZZzayZSpym9lYgYfi0hLU@39/@Qu0YY53bHgX61zdE4RYSVFky@8S70K6qGEreVs6H4sVcsxCGGxhCHtzeEHDqNHSaoHUdBlpVXEdyMhXyh5FTvFkmDUkUyHWZCh7ClgZcYEyVpBlkMqEoiUM2w1ltoHMG6MpvjzJrUSwA/gizTl0ldp040mEJkNzvC2CDnS4RtjP88NG4ZWtzTvWbGVTUlJLSNzaSVm7@qz0/w)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/pg1we)

ReactOS is very fragile. I had two systems in VirtualBox which stopped working, ReactOS 0.4.13 broke the next day I installed it.
So I copied cmd.exe from ReactOS 0.4.13 and test it on Windows.
Command line: `cmd /q /c polyglot.bat 2> nul`

Note: ReactOS also supports all the variable substitutions mentioned in the previous answer.

In ReactOS `set /a x=2222222222` sets `x` to `2147483647` as opposed to `-2072745074` in Windows XP, so it can be separated with `x>0`:

```
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
```

*In IE 3.01 HTML comment is closed by `->` in `aa->=323`, so I moved Maze below HTML.*

Answer (score 5):

## 347. [dotcomma](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma), 15824 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8;[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl6154op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92g=1*\'\0C0ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7p3qpStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HTGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr3uBnP4vhxZ461qxvOWM2Nrwx67rmqeHK7N6M3dVNL69lBQFjbbv9ydCwx15FiDGVMUu3@xO9b7CeaY0NN808w2Btw3LOIFxjbHNiTzyjW4e3LGO2ccb27I7ZBQhs7JwYtvnGcCEsx9h9w7oYXoxZxxkOdbvrsZFr2mMKzTP2VIeX3qRzwvS2N3b1zth0bAgqMPbMtvRhu6szij5yDZ6oyABU54TSLIaUGHvsuJ4BOTgdw/Mc9CyDp@6azqPtJx9fia9m2Mc6IDWyjOmV7FWVPTcNt3s1hcY@O3rw4Kpvln0qOTZ7cB0lNce2J2Nnb3wVfp5t9w1bZ5pclrWrgQUg5tiwSplSZiEIwh6YLtSi7tcW6@g21ArW2QYzhqPxjEm8nnXLCuvQY7rHJt5EtyiePRm2DTeI6I11d2zafXZmjgdsPDC9MB3F9kZ6x5C6hmUOzbHRZZYJiZyeDwVA2112YszOHBeq1ofp2NYMEhods2dikgAPAIhXYjwwOJyhPoPKtMfQCJjOPEDDMgJoSSEG8e8b7UmfOZPxaDJmgFvX9PS2BUDbM9Y1evrEGqdZG8KAmOR/NjBsv9ECOBlAHDkcq1cTQs2Yt22922UZaK@Ax4nBTKAaoVVh2Sz4M8cFqkGsACMfGLVfXkZjCnUDVd5zKiyfyUD4buiD2OqW5/jILKKGgTb0SaozhPvUdfquPgRqdA2i6Wd7T5nXcVx4gx/G5f3mJjAdfcw2N1l898n9OKuH1SK7bSGsoho7hyqIBYHsVLcm0EKiNeFA/bhhagGrLL4Wr7A4kEXLsFyO5aB7lpiWByKpmTI4oJ9rWRV@BaaVWE6FnpKPpzGfnqv3TcvgUPoIpYgNXMszDe6ZHMuqJR6z71g9Hq1DmRVZtsQKRVbMsyLcy6ysQW4IOsfUch5@BfgBtDKgosIvm@OA5u0e2im2tR3W04emNfOhE/gOy6usCBABXxUgayWAAM9sFn9Z@BFai1cU9ngA1B7opwBesswT5DpGyHiwChV4KBsbCnE@ZK08e2@A2QPpgGj5EitC9gWgRA5QAMpqJY0XwhsYluUnGXiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdO8EMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPt0YDvW2MzQ5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZIEcWqjabw@wvBei8fEiOsj7gEM@x2yMjQ2YNjMohNjxvjwk7YDVJ4IyLXBPYmAXtEoaKjo4sDTu4QQwqgGOOZQaZwPhpOKc43hOXWcjGI07UdnF4h2Gja7guw7ggE3hp4lnepO0Zryc4MM3x6gETNIBX9nTTChGgjqmPiaPCM@5BfrNFtHuuM6TeO0SeZDnOaAX/Bw54hoAeOmfGHPU5g9RHIwuGIfA3@CgIyJzpJKiQVBPNlSMEiTBdZ2ACQMoK2LfpGh2ivV90SJ0FRr@IYoVp9TtZhHIvMj5l2cgB3u1hGntiWRUYOIwOy9aVrnGqoA8fwxbHLsQhGNVgbPJBtHUQMhBzwiKEdEeTabw8CmrWc4aLReMMay8s@sDEkcY602dQez3gVcZUH4IoxFDesGF0HEKL4TWINQHCHhZrj3UdOz4OoZy5IBVAocOSkOSBNBmbQwPERgeSYI3nCGlkl4RZewZNmaiVk0lO5JhcIZQsXCUU98hFPHhngfGzO@kg1TBv06YWBOOOh0KTa@hd7ieMXXZ8rMPPhQFy5IvGMjow4iGiFpHgYHQ1gPq@KNMhiDjoG7YH8pgnMxMFV2j5facHje3MhLKDqARJ57A7RAQkQeg1lTuyQCTHBjQ8sZjJOqMRA38QQKB5PsiUYEx3XpnsDQRaA5DJOhPXnbHpCGrCHEKsccfp9aD1vjFGAwDBhl3WmXWge0IlY@sRug5xpM5osZjzt3UD4tgo5e08/RrrG0B2kAB6KNZjk58XYDSiIhApdJtLB7YOlMIidEYzIguACVP0HEdG/65jeNRYHPck7PqYmWf0qWtAP@vNmdEQpR1opTZJaV3gPH73QviYobC0MJiV3wo@NmzoOh1oldDpofqwTrdZD7STiEyAgpve6Rijsd9OHGJnph0RoPYfoABFvpIPTPYGwvpdtnml1UDUsOVEhAMUKBH1kS/X6chrfRUIxAXbmMvwnLNYs2vZQ4zTK7mLLzHOAgYvxRU4jKhLoDRJTGIyRlaC3NHsDJAXjpHbkAADvc2dXC8@@EWzd4dM6oV5IzYqsB1BVkIvxGM1DAl@1nVA8shCWPUFD4y64HELaN0bLoHshEha3aivrOgyMMXbgA4d21kCFYgZwsUoiyFUF9QYD5Fr6FbYGKm7eAt1hAx7rpXjQAZj6GjkuNAzONOZkWpGVRZpXb5GkwjHiiRo9ItDKwwZcRzwxzgKQoKRBXocdTHsqSCq6sApgIlxjQN4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidEevnjQnGUts2UNrV3RkHAsWD4RkymjHTdYENnuIgwcegYDCRqZ3CmAC6F3JWJAf1@6uZy9iidyZtc3pVremgp/zKE051l/VQo3FB6IBOlIj3vHiySv6UMhIkKs5orFBSfhchIkWSocoTPVCSYJB4AIzmcGZ3EuJCFxPTTJyMeyUxCQ5MyGU09ok@Gl/F7hX4YaMZnkC/prcq68PwLUlwl9CPMMEARcYA3QU5AzohiO7lcretswvgHqCeT3coNQqZ9FTlXJiXYXfDvHxCIC7R8so8C8/tkEOKjGpYAoxOJadBYoGA70kJSiiCh6L4Yyt6kLTHw0iu4Z4TmyYwWIKLIkl2Hgr7MAAkCBkThA@zY45bvrhy504guKzVatDYQJoCttlNRtWEYKZHBk4NkWWSRvxM5LFzOMa@kUhCeTHyJccGxCZoqbU6Ox8PXOhx9H4pQCQgq2BjSw4I69fzE/Nk0r1a0TZ6YiQRex0ITWZnLFYFGPx5b6jdRNX4AlVBlYgjVbHxYnoCfa3xki9WqOhHcw0Pxd@aj0qkhhOIgd9Wl5KIJ/X95g16Z9axfJGAu6Czc27UBvRP/JmBkBGlfZkg6LTXeioHgt2Bw2FPt48e1vy@yAOVtmlXFjwsp6Nb5L2O0cUg7aO9ewfbB19rLYFhme3KVQ/FzJUKONROplLfnig5WausR2HMAd9v3QwbEy7GEQU/mEnONCIqzTowuEwDcu4ffHqVJCAJITkoB3Dj74pIw@OA0CW0dW9wZRBm/VQKsgyTBHGZtMcCmKEDUcdwPcDn6eTNG6y8q0iNfH/EzJroHEDgqezZQToZA68IYEFQu8dHREoLUqhp4wzt3BWNGeDzMUrNV5EhUTrSZD7ef7B7UCOw/mSFRFEUbwyylO52ZWjz1qRrCMviAPsDV4el5DniKE8TrksJ3OksEHhet2wFfACAuo7sMMkaBkXzBoD7ztWyka/UCVsAvROEq3JlVB7qfCiiETxwiOugyrtsFKWA@WAVei0dscLQxWGrk88bxVw5Omx15nl2o0BplhXGgUBudCHoxJPQR55Lkb5Y7aN/@Oga4h4JkaAKSAFmnsVkysuzBNReJJPFPWUHNDTHMuTnxPFEJiYVJR5MtModj5TPSPzdqTlOZJL8qSYhLuS@vb2n3Q8i@3OANJNBSgPq4jgyuT1cGOl40EZsx3L6DtuANFw6DDIEsWllMbf7jn2thnT0xKLGcG0F@C9O3OgjGGvMN6Q4UqqouspXaXTbOwMurRaySCSiEIFSKL78Sj/VgVzzch/ufbELg4iaz2RCd4YuIEEkDZELXZ2IL3kwCTKSfXyWFjBcZ7nW24MAKbLQgYX2GV2YcHsevNSTOKasLI2/FKVPnGsUf@XMrjQt8OFNCxwRku09efpo78nu4@3Pj8daPr/wnsuUC0A4yK8NspA84HTD3rrBuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xAQQmm3yeeC4xbxigyR2BFq@ErVIlPnIEd95JXC3OGodIru8Ob0GPsfDyqnxAU7a6FyojLl/lwPMf2MxiPR15FUaCXDyZtGZRW5VXHsfS@QulgYLAsRUXVZW8f5zW8ZSkAGW9m8BR8cgtEhxnNIOrW0AHlhRYLkTWwBAdPs1aW2R@ALowrioablMMWTKVRuqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1StxNu1mtFyihhEW@j@EHetZ4DqlIDRCkiRvPLKju8c32Ez4NII6SqQGJM3aJLDYzgWWAwESZo1RT0/IA5xC5wvRV5BNHo9wdlc4FJKPpMrqoW8AmoZqGkgs0o45yYN9XFnII0dCeBJTo/mDSKtsOd1dLsnb/iOAFmQ@z6ComYbL46P7SYI6Md3CDdcyGvMmg21mayy60k2/PjJKrTeheJh2w08oO2SE5omPdkKftbVr7Ozrk69q8uU8XDkjznSiD3eBkHqjQP8umtE@x4mUKKBysZCXAUjv1WWTAhZmFTAG1JKgQ4FIy00PQXxkkDoRfEQWg7wrUgCNp/N4OXgC@MRPoJKN7Z704l7NPOPcg3OlnojICJNNneQS3s4PziG0TFs@ciloXKRSbMzI47z6LrHZyshkb9oGqQHXS2EQLPy4Yy0HS4HQyOgVKSeA@eAdoXTpoP5LCMq/dDSIEPCCScfQIKwafWgD3wGEvOCbPOC8JzIZ7FIJ7ZzZiO0tsFKUtsc88l@Z@Li4qHZjZYNomc1HgegUeEifJ1WGdtGh8@y8sRUClACdTY0hg5OJYB0RazAoCLofIUSdUEPZ6yhW2UkXIYB@BK7uwNcrGPw@SJpiEoUNKldFh@7yrb0haJLb6A13yBbYeG3o0vsVOlHAQEW14tplsSfASXpxBlSpOc034KB9wJxVxjNxgMoMbQwUa85I8O@qvNxjTCRrNK6bjwODN@0E@fxtbW1eCVej6fBtQWuTXRtoSsFri1ySeTCeDK6KEWaXBjaoBTo14xfNgLI02QT28AUJYc35iihNyqVbDOtN1T/qeEzCVUBlIfYEj4ATjxZq6EzmRTrZ7hmA/J7pOw72HYOO6458knwCQgE/N2nQZaIAOo9SvOuUUXd9GaKDGsuKI0GipgJN37cyBw3j8@Pu6njy3gaUyereg30Q2Be48RQ7rvOZASCWyNXkYC3JRvZSrParsUz8Y1EoiRZkJGeTH5USqZ0TutE3IA2lTg@jgNJfeo0OgOX4E3TWjIZEgrw6JmgZVhWIi6flyD/drKZTMUhbTKeBrZci8eBLh0kgkeFxhkB3ogemFMgJXRMGOKiawrEIGlxCrvrF8ZoMHOjEcJZN5CycQZ9vviPeySQi0e55BuePirQLWj6gdzL44Fwi5N3KC@NZpy7CxzTY2Vh60ow7p5KvaEz1pXPZFCa5MhwGV@LK5IEIyGFcEhU7Memh11Ytw1n4kVnGpdOgGLu4Hs0mACzDPb1pKFVmSPB6AwcFl@/C9BZuN6DQwkuXUl8ASwA0O3I8EMmilIJLpaAdEE7NEzgi7S3hWZlVEKCs55gbj5fGL2Ww9yqlIZlMCOzbzuuIQFJIIVA21FoM5NQZ/6OmD2a@bq2LuGH0pCGirdpAEd8YDk60Zaz68h60GgYSQ/6OSQ5MLqCBfyjB@xR5nXhGl1lQ6BVWscdwAgBpUFOrIW1NfQDFMcbdeXxFJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh84x1NU0rdPK9ShCGrQKIPYBKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzLp4UCHf3J/v1dPndCgy0OrziP1ho63QnIlb7edGDY/TTbhfZk2s7QBDIE6d@cWAeOM@ZaPrysmpnhSrM5nFg6zflcnZa5MV3HaTsWTQXdlHQef@J6uqXzSaggdPuzxyDrPzs6rMmVSCRFPx3emDfOQy7PltNzL7rmSOutwfKQxxumuJ4XcdwKtsshm/EDChgw8TfLQR0F/kX0D7oUrqH4/iX0H@JGOZCV/VkEeg09/Yhlioib53AHke95rmYu0X@lDhbGUykeFxzn2J6rGvmfjnu9Be8seZ9IyJqsuXeOvPkmugUdMYpSnkfCHXULcaKAChQn3Fh3NZ7PvMK9BgPDClYQD0AwwVUyGNstFJ9AN0FJnO99M0CQHuFiCHFoXGJjHZA1vWvTFtCnRhKPLcTWqJ/AGKag5CKsK8yf4q5ST7Edf2nS49zTAdWeZk8263wxG1Unl2ttCp98X28BiM16NdiotCoa5hSPh9EIKuEGKaiYtH5/rajhbgyP5tQFSlIVPAW0hqmWkY6nxd3mRVzxiAw9Jh4fTz/KaJ@D@oG7zNbvKH2jihmuolc1CIn7omp7xiQQ7DAWn5/uDICdsNR0kZRQPxO751hdiS@GQbtgXI3CCvL3IoS73/xNjobpBhvfaOchT4psNLJn7hrcK1Vavx4hsssuBAS95JxdnKRPL1gDRrZT2RtZ5rjJLuWx0xogScYT1766H4@Lmq6rzzzB38pSY9sHH3/WyDQ5BGGo4wJXidfiNNjWCfIxyEO4zxZcuCFnbI5pwKcNByaWV5UBqSmthQD6AINnUGVhRn6JEPUL42Jelp4BCmnCQMy92TDNjOSl3LP08diweZvjq4yryc2Xg/xsapT9lr@2UGEZWoABAdTEMECxyg6P7u8eHMjQcr1EfBcXairQHfXOAOSQVYUOKBktfIV91I2zjzBNErVzAboaKBktPz006io0elAzIHdkEX3DTYBnEtdYOuBNy1qUkAtiPoFwW1VnTDQKgSWMJJSJgFWW4v/M5hqVj2cFWnyKKAnkTtypAG3NpDyxzdeyB@MJiacQJc51UhgWausJYmrrapJaj2sOcYUYFCmSDaEEjQaT3gDTg8giazarfKkf4qKe5faRuqJIVUG7f2tqUPU18AbJhSD4yWtv2YtGRio3U@vLQNEeMn/jLi9/BC5CWATtGUuzXU9Qf7/WkTkOfMmPM/JnpDVf2Z1eYevcIfKpZYoe7IsipkPbqBa3Qy1utoJOhqyEZlywIAFLiPnbqv02S@HE@UG1wWTkkUiy85DoGpKcXVwQDdm6xoiG4FIZr4zLQMkExvTIgdI88rdUR4UA6q3@fhHss8eCGGhTiwuyGMIldeX0ihAqnYrRdFwINO0Th5Z1QlcrI6t5FPzC1MMT63rKnukN6LYQNcSBx9VWYecN2z26LYlAqxv@ujl50Ly5L/KCrKgrB/SgKfQlOS/uFVnItm30JnafFhnRzaTXt8SUyiWK3Gu3zVVRgQi4/St4LokGTArbsybnZDXYo40zLjAeAePiSsq86Fe3GbEFusPoMIZU/vO/fL0L9L9eOwMYKHCCMXS0YOjGmpJ6KyvLT4ovdFtesXwefGKZOhGGXLeB7OguFEm3Qsdy0LTWLkkw/A9x5cCvcWibeAPh8IZmxjHnC3/Bc3kmy9bObGCZnVVxr2y74lnRKg/ob10iAheCTIMSEevilWBM@UpLRJNGNnY7UsHeKEaNmdf7YDKe8DvIp7dWojnC301904@Zyett1QANUW@bxg1V7uonk64jjU76oZxaWBJ3Xnpa6pVAHPBXfVvoXF58XkDX7MM4GzxXRZsPbcoZPW5rFZ498UZSm5TtLn@jjjC8IQfX4vdVUUz/cFPoWE0106Lbe7ZEHzo0FH/Tg4JbSqUI0cwrZLb09gxlkMGHt7JwAwFwnFonlcpkV6wgj0ar06PCSOnL5eWpp3KH02PZVIDCt61KfLKMCuxvZL2lVmG4Moe6JWndiHMlM1@2/@Ba1HDpktIYp7hwc7q05ubUxwGpM7F0d@66oYnP8QhWC1ZNPPvDxlOz44A4MGJqUVa1YOiIDBjEMoMdcPOMcNcw3SK7HMxlZOyCWoiDuBS6lrMApzPGnaEr2tR7MDS@IxP3vUYaieysolTHOcPfSvFhAKopvy8f0d4sxeo9mJNkdSwdxvGVw8HCHCDOMd7SUM9Mz6DbcsKeLEV03LGW@i92gWB2Lzpbd1uz9kzL8dgh3W8iUN8FKvD78gYdpaWp2xLNeUfdN/CgYCvDvEJ1q@9YhVJf0eG2stYnbg/5vv98Xw4XcihVvYVDBeKPY6v@cyVfP1Hck9sqiA56ubiNNeK8YYhdxqb8JZbVpQPFANfnlpfsQaZEKWWFz@ityBhXVs70WfD8OYaOVaQNho7RjMRpkO4wQbkEjrHLReyfJ7fczbl1348pXQNbvK0Qkco9sQwYrOh@rUqZllE/MIWaybw/i@pZE2NiLFU09tuvDDx2fIOS8f5IZfxirPsT8rgGgCdQwlhvfM3wvbDGcRrfbmQmumV2jNtFmUWmNgLpe4Sq81NwPEXH9RR9ezJaqNUF7cw@uJlkg1HQpZ3uAnYY8qF8qHSLpLQgn3sG/W7UmLiGh/vAarlMJuMLMJGFlYWXmzSpbJj2lcnvCxmTzzzneVxcTHMjzuV5EFmiOw1XsiBtlWJPkctlxTZtYzzD@3ty07bjWB9SU8BUuyaKYiBZ0o7am2rsmrjjnxVh86kLDyc82r1VkxZ8tPF1S6APKs03VXp05ee9alPCtc0hrjstvt48fRNZR7otFzyvjXNCfI@ttVqW9GdDVLkkF2/sdVxCddqGpfPHtJC7CV5Zzt4Ib5Fp@GuyuIbLV27nK@6xK0xpNANimV3QUgbG0KDXG6R8vYumBfzHykhTB3@rgqeG0VGmu0ZnVYSRCXzBxvvCUnFEWBo7NuhXY9zOh3qKhRtGfd9VHDhY3FtK5L2h3je4TYubOOV8wgI3zXC1bu5cPnVR4RtlOpBsbsRgdZOATnVizLzguRTg41kH6nUyvH267Urn7@Ac6Hv09lU7Va8PsfbAGdgDY8C3h4dvqzoHtMcxt0FyE@qAdX@AO9ZGo4Wd7FF6Wo5lvQ89kTVyRuk4vaU47eIZVzyg9UFwZ3obAvzHrZN3@pjzDnSs7DUDYwLjkueMnZEh0duqqBZO9PD7Kh4arEX/vDNIN@r5QJHg@fPCv1W37OvOeDSiR2tkTTy6UVKJjibfJjf1@A4U2vvouH35jTNsy76n7G9PoSXw5SymbY47Azwbzlu20XfanYF5G9JtQx/b5okSTPnw1/fSXZEyJpPuo7dsmUBedyZje6lFww/xsbeq0v3ZIz6shY4b5JVlM3R0@loa6Scdj8@GootVcEI40hv5Ge0KnXKvvJ6Y4znQyJalcHqXL0ugYxXu/iaJlZIVHYWYs2F/88TKVkpCOgrkkpEBgUddle3idrZIF8tm@W0VQtFSEkaR7ScfQm5/iw/NDpqReVvwX2hfC3uTlg5y9mDS964zTD5d3wURDW@rpy1oy3JkyhrGLN32H6vIrFkKnmWEZwtkrolx45pK/sZFFYqnWpLumPBowQOqbrJyDs0yRx6/M6m3cinO37IEuvjV9UJOm9lyZdqvmK7R40sg6LpNRBw6Lm44BhlE6uBKOs6gIzPnghdnXLbTB6YuWWweOYi7SmxZuhtoefWHY6b0@ROjr@OW6kfmGPdkLmkV1GSX7SK6FfZXJ7pnfnUCJVvV2NAwA1@GdKMn@PFtCbzHet/sPFyoiBBJn8D@hk7@WGj@6HW9Ls4Gpoc7mkLHDRNT2OR4I8ZW1wK9YUnMq/P2oU2KeQfipx2Xxl42t@6MZngobEaum6bVzTHNsvrPVarjqr1eNyJxNhmOJp7/WI4D7ZmKzkIPT8jfOzMBuPQaWCsb6NZ4@Ux1ZMoVpDB/UJw7V0njX5iW02dflDIMhDYQwlA4X9Jw7sHw/BQ35Lj2kpZIeb/nsidOdEguL9hrqFsjyyTTNsc3z@aMx7g5J3hiYfjIgQcRlEd4l@9@KATpaDlFHt0u689PIN8yvkPLO3QmbsdAZ2hWJKoW@LkaO8EmYzy44aBZlLOoltZxLOhe4LCWdpmOY0/GkjuxbxwVCjeOChU2LRUizYAlvrr7@Fky2hpoU/ZtUqgByt/Es2Zz18oNA1camWmDILaajy7GDnSJ@9wc0gHtCL4lzTbabOoQu77vLNN3ns5gAHlvhQmY/2R43@jgsuGteT9xHju2A6PRCBjl8MDgR/sXNnosT4jJHuHhdaBP99ZsDgnsikGISxv6yGhD/Vpz1/uMRRzwfX2srxiKaG6Q9L/QdWtbMa224b6iSb@Ie5VKu4jQQ2NKusXqBsP7oDTudLhIjPNxC31kYcXGGzmOze/EbTPwUB/fzFVgKKDb@y@Uy7jffmFeYKl@tljU/VO@S8ToctsTq8rqGm3H4vcb9iTZJt8ToLum4SmP0JQB@RVyTALpy7uRhxRv5CFz1Qgk2VPdo0X65arGHKQ6/YAtQAPd7Ti4EuY7btidE7E/cAubDrfw840DbSD8FDiW3pn4RhZvQ8satod0W6kwRGrzwGjj4Z82Ge0Y69PrlclnhnyLBZEdXeE5/4BdYacusMRT0EaStw9bC3rUIlXNEd2IU69cLqfNOpJtGp03Os6aOUSv@dz0QjiUWXlCzhVz1ZFuRLPIik4H2pf2pMWtayDQWIY0Hrig8yvjm6a3A2sqS9ZDJkMDF5kXV2FWiq6ON6DCOsvX00Pm6hqSb9IPeElo3o/Lh9L2SskTwcP//r1PFBiEW4VcYGEEWNftK/iA/MS1/cf7tMCnjjfumdN9wBtPAaxiJ1isPCSBB@8Z6NpYVQioPXti8dmHfmTf1bBL6phE1mslySJ2PTYkwz6VyN7b9HqJHH62S9lGq6djoyv55g5wpUF6FBzzCqP5zyULqFHeiJs9VYUTdlrI@ds/lxH3LOAMIG85Y2nk0VMZeU/3Hu0fySNPXTo@bQ/wdMQ1OW7BfoJWykSmpF7pbmS9k29H65reWLl3qEo7j/ZkjLCC3nxFQ4IHrswtPFbOe/pmRXVFX6kFYagxXi4gPjx6/Cg1P4nJEjsD1xkayWjwzuFhGk@afHK4NDia@gH0jp4zXZl8b1dVk0ua7zObVgdXcc8lOa2CdGSANgqN8SE3v3KrcNVxRkb3aDYyPoPBEzm4957ZF1YW8ol@avaxF7LySkJRR2VluZBLRnZmg7JtuOFzVX2emCPklh16KPyxcjsKSg5Zxc0ulx5uWvG/KsWwjL8T4cMSqZnrrXVsStAz@gN0Kbr390VMVdVVdD7Ue1CvLL@yshYjLFsftpzT91hKNnzlRQq9pDG0Ksm8dR95URoC61bwhtPzvic42yu3wdwEIPQuLO3wZ4Y9022J1rJuEi8qkBo3td0Y5QvjPRakwh0@p2joeekaX7ilniU65EzekvGRG0mys3Nv77YEBz4tb4718ZNn7Knuoa2RmyNGMTbeA@O5ZPRKwnkrNHS3cjm16wIo7UZ4/dHy/lxhh7rbdezZ9PZFODpqikM72RAOYeEbRTIsc2ouG6s6fF7r6fJtRrflzQ9xOLMFOThqg8YH9O5b/0JVMxmyMIRPNcNfb6mZoIOzBLr0GZqtiwYd7YWsoYNyiwweyaXa6CNjittR@GzwMqV@6fhWuGHsKyZXDyc3hZVuCMvdkN@1MPRkWTmj3gAwf0MYy8th8CPHOhs48o7uGt6S/cdLEbqpIOUbClKOcOc3pQxOgtLCou9eLeLj0QX/sbS1HhljNzcaOG0zt7QM2z20Jckeo0306@H@dgrdpe0tfcc/8sHfl@d3NjGWZvRYf7M8gDjNydIgYILGYEJHIq4HLy6QtkHmNey@yc0osnvOeJfeliL51MEd60uzvG@O7k9GqxEFlohW/K9y8YWIz0FVds48dg9PxM2l8yUqP26LW@6/SpRl4XwgGhF9eLQdNKr9Q0WL5DjH4vOnC954ZnS8fxjxc43pdJWuK01XqY5LQ@a5PjnKLWS7WX9xuoRYq48ZgZQBbDh8rhR/OI/75PA6J0CtbTAeWkHIJ7o9nyhdqLCuM6YDhtcD@fnEg4kdNWHtpX0jJPw8Lz9F6cmBnfFEwk6lksnFr2REj4SiodfEOho6XKfjnxD34oKt@UcuIUAMDnH6h0zRHhqogAaeEhUIxLi2DtnUamq@zLbw0xQVEPCSlCN6kdWpIK8GWz/3z09WKuolW6sxsSIy/wRraESWG0IFuGjCEcrEpBOVrY8hZD04fcnIpj@7YKQ0gpSq5jPwJivRc@hV/3wqoLR@/nTv6e7h0fbRs8NGpnnpn18NCmHbkFtwSv6jbFeEsvtkg8GIm0Wmc9MWZEffG0Bl0wvKxaBkV4pWWyjavFDiFqZZP7dtRaEjvIp0CfhJIs@NQkGyRC8OOygx1Y9/ervCT9PSoWCoIg5apDyhziossyzjkQ6Mdd32w69@Q4VC8Rs7FfzKDmbsW7KFhth3nK6fo2ew268gxwfbe4@eHeyyAMF5ozkzu@NBrZznho65WQGop55Je5pqLO4niUNd1WrxB3EgTFyOswoduiYjw9DOIVpAHTyu7afeYIl1gg8UjIeVovyXryuXcRm35yYhbjxAKg7ZQpOnhrK2tsaOoJGw@wd7n@0eMMR/9z55I4kQBDvCE59/9uMuN9MfGF4Jvi/kDokdkoELIXrqOzgKPT@tjTSnrjta/ZUhMotPZ6JDe/zhB0UEgT7XAO32jGymXbGnlSQTN/yrSL65syAjakKBaW@cCUbTZa7HTk3PxBPZiEMPLYktNnbcPELW82S2jZ9Qwg816fTNCEB9Yo@5tR7ftkcMWpocspw0Wydk@RcmxEjE@OYaNPa2AQMk82xQr41xhb2CloizrRV@Yl@S6vFrSQLQFXJJyF0jEa@ZHvOUY1d592v/TOlXGbjH4P62755m7sHbr/hvPXD/Kne/ULChXTdVNsclihCaF/RLwBEJ6Y@0j3w5yuZWEuaEQ4tqAV9l5hCq6ZSojtF5DvwuATuew0k0PoNKg@YGNeZbR@D5GW4zgfYNK4qCTQqFNpn2phtTvlHsip3DQr6QUxVAUjoNAJJh8j6egOUAk8kKdBPh1BzVXoJEsLm5yUTU3IxaocprVlm3X2TFlyGi6xBXOBsgcg0GaSDJPAWE1f1kMPik1CQmRe4VV@PIuLoOjEoUjqMXvts@IUSWAGJxGhlo6XqKHxkbu7PAXmcbP8sV@WjFug9IUmFMIldSFHy7Ak@cMTQf6KTzz9JwuwK4UZKPgGgIz@Of2CMzmdge5es9a34cNvg6ht/XZOQBHFQ2c3Uwjdat@BxBHCKIiris@TZesOPxsd1UeNtk0Ex/sKQx2@D@ZaW/os3ycm9fN5KYuGriEInF7h7aDqqoD6AwLKEpWlZRC8l5kXK5pUXyS@RnA8VBEy0XkB2wKWAZHcN85Yy87Z3dvU/2nx5eMwRIMeNXowHfr2@mjiU53WiGjni0WItVcu@Bcvj43oOgIuZIFyLcGBi/XxL1ppLMZ54Q5Pwkw9WiLcPwaulWY/ycn3W@im9Wuwk1SnQNDzXzAfnSbmLpAZ0Jupq5VlpGrXz@JpTm8JQI6B1@oPMaqonk@WWjuVk/tmPx6y1hSUd4EZM3sBOA69jbWFewsV8vHBYs/PjlEX4dy4v2xezyviiuZ9EeFZ4nHzsnc0tcvkckIFLeIBtgkYKsBFFX9r59LqPP7cVp/OOc3HJV1C5PBOFC5iaKR0AdBd/5RC4yt3bpG3ocgI5jmW0hsIfEDT4GdulCW4/cllEiKfjfTOAZJ/wvf04rU5m2DiWSyO0IVprdZDsygJcUoEOjdPd0ArrVU2fEbWjTEvF9I3AdOMB@QfMl3dJgn0yGEK9HjwODpuuBc0uQGCgZD1HlshRwCd905DSFxjkhvwYakPQLLg@7@cQ0KQ@MadfsA29PJNPA0T5S1SYLzUtiocmcpB0Xqc7mtXBjV/wYj@lGyf5BNkancwT0hi6D7mpME/GzeLLShPzRP372/DSeFJe1JbJ16hv/7F41ehqiX1Rv5iT62O@dgUXRZdyiXL7OJcDvKmBulSv4gE@5LA88gT7IVkPJ/XDsPgIniBGJ3lAfscTE5hbNZEavieOEnSZTT1KdG0W0WSpFChU8KEBmlLJHLj5@J3R7xhJKDRoB@np2Fx9vzBFrqLLcBDdlkmTr@GGtHZC40JRfUgAdGJJUCGwNmxCoGYAR7yQyb@CQBsMhLjzILtySYPrOEM1qOkgTKjWr32GRD6UtSo5iuVzxK3SRK5YZtL7r7FBWAOw1PhfI9UBd39gJ0AzUX1mIzRn5dY4Xo3xjHJGHvpUUQCcWMWQaGE9hAGtuZrQzcPGX2LWhr4B8UKk8O3rQKiUVkYXWVvqu2cVZd26LO1Tx/K@nQDdVFqLGq1yj@xiToV27FjfngubVHlCHEa@w1FiUDFe/Zzxvm6p6Y6v3E/q1ADFzOAD4p9JaATg04Bjsf1gStpzZ/@xn@MVkMbGuqict9zQVz2eqcFOreZZnH60fS9J6I1O7u66DFjV@PT0GnVzZyN0/NQa99l5fORZFlmU5Rdk4P48/2HhqvtAKr6eXWbX0@mSkFhry62lTLNXSJ0329Onnb1tvk@L0dPZaPE5o9EXfnf0LUc2hoh@rlNn5ViEbOynjxzGZrudP2BT0VnbC3sB10mP4T@433YhbR3e794Y@KhQXWez4GL@ELBZFRWnEm/BP6v5LuLji36jLdXmr@fZtsqHr4@mMmaY58rpd@DkDkCC15CGDfO8Ap6f4CjumJylQdA2nvfk8gp6HW13DI4ry3Rb6kInE6bbR70929Zk5eTB@/MXz4HqG15uDJRMSzVQqIUmNq96Vlp6PMS2j/dlP1i7T509bm3/2jaFirOFjHx/fvnyM7kM1/9Ha2kf37uVyaU3TuPvpF0@/tr29nbufzj9t5LdyUmZt80//ZG1N0zY1Za3peWoz3jg5@VzUMjlR/rMfxVtPn37V8@rZ//Prb@sq3opwO2VF4BNwZZkKTryX4KeijPW@V@xNDFq5GpvRXysW@J@vMbW@Vfyv391/HRvH6pry3IXnOPY6VijFuBMc8JYN3k5j9dgmRitcxmZKrVYDZ/G//jtIX/8E4GDIbBNu9XwAqzCL1aUaJbmI1QvgUDUN8v2/v/71CIacTdRIjAuuu6wBl5grauJWE64NujYFtGInZRQliGePB2PDYWrpjnoHX0x4gYdtoNVvY3wcw0/Nsv27jB00UqlUU25JcMkvcI5IUVXtWFXvADeQPtqo1aQNxs30ZbP5O2hROEkzWn0HBkzjDnv@j3HFlnlWPxDIgRArrN19eb9eh6Jk69mNeoouv/9QVyqWRMe5K7I0exkHxaPRfPmI9xdWFzMlTUyn07wTTZFA0nTefuiT9DF@hT7YUdlVv4UkEMX3jX14vNguXn/@v/359/78u/T3Pfr9RzTuZ3fNnrIBkU6hI9ThulupdOp1se6K58f4XofWk6mUKiWldXmc2AC@0zxgaubji3g@Gz9k1IFUxo6TlBouyrbuZ4/v9djcu8596lE/P4BHJg/ml4IcC1Qjd0i1a/FgQPW3QUqN03pTQjGoJjXUQr4p8VQBlvUya9yFahK1Ylls1rW8tg9Vp4q84gbrHnNioA8WAjr6@NbnZauHIfO3etQrVg@S1edxPjRegG5diDUaStOgYSDwY3fXKmulSqGiKa3Q8/rFqte9DMN46sVOY@HFqRObEzQWNs2rfkFVhC8saMHsQ@IJMclg/8AXQN@Caw3@6B@u8BXva@Tje1OU69caq6gbWlbJf1TY1T4wfwGGB9Zpt9tvOm0c/fW23tHVsT7Rp/pMH7cn7Wl73JmgZZ73L5MQe9tYYwecDTVZKriOU7dez2S55TvJ4eBPkpxpTIj9I1x1VVPZBgxLGbiBLEZOUJXxT1UFFjuHq/l2o/F2A3poPbVJ7LFZl3ws4SG37jZT0uVlA9zVqv@/WQ@dVbq4CwrXvEylNl/UQeJ4UW@kAOQLH6TMYcqtenOTAsK8/Mz84M0miCxSarOxWXN26AdJ4JKaAHBzAcl4zokXnLt3UzK834X09fUmS6ZS65K0huNhwx8pIEWzngqKhBgkQEI4P/85f6DcQYe93LysXzY2Ly83N@F/k@6X/hN8Lzev/dNjfq2IMw9vImM5bij1Y@XYZxNNeJeVOvrIyjE46vCEeI2sVmo20AGX3Pxv819Oz@@hD6LclAFrIbbBNmJoaC4b2xBiL999@b/g7/jdl7@PMiKDP6MixM6xTysbqGGWuaIJN2Y/ttljftngxl/wij7o8biOnja/2bgIpSgvZVbh8/wJtVRIyjj8tpxeC8@uy@wlREVhDUYlJmqlgthKqTONxTbFQpHGpV@8dsXj8X/yUisX43xKBo9cv/Q873EEtxA79hhiV7WMKqkXdW5WnH/o4ReXXf/kF1ddQuyizIwKkKXjMU4QIQbtJyZJMEjVN4e4JxcXRSTUP09rn0vPtiWcMNHHtOTV4ZMBtb3dWrlc5@s560@pr2zc34C7Cv@7a1AMIdZ@jX@P3uAfO@rg38Fr/GNHb/DvYIx/7HEb/45e4992G/@Ohvh37zX@PR7j37M@/h3/QjarVsX1cyJASi2rl@tTkQhRjW3Vj3@B104v/tPvfOMb8VotLsXpCxM51XGZmqwCCT0vXr0bF2I1tq6uqxkr08mobbUNDpNlXJYZZAZqF2SilsoyBsvMMjOWGTpqF1wG/GXAZWZ6LNNnGTtjQ0QIBde4lRmjqwePPvz1AJALfybuE2urmQ6DjCxUPujTdAgeXBetY6HB4kx8aYBmKKtyRi6YTfygR0N8@fJY2Whq5RKTsWHIrcbL43gTTT9r5Rxrz4y145cs5oFqWY0px8cKnySDshI5Li9brd0n91stBUeK48fO/vx/f38Yfb3xf7jvPN53hg787@/vQwM36qm7KekuXDXgrf5jK1avbh1XiDUH7DmmbG4d17MSugspYLka@qU@8JpDhGd97ViInyVQKzhDxaD6/Kx6WiX3WfAKjlZ1HiGIxh3@E64zGIUCleEMrtMzdNAbOs@eH4cu7lCen4HXcwYqUfgPqlf09R/g3/xv6//xM5ZkiUYzmTi/3EzQlcS/ZPL88vzSv9eTiYT/ktiEP/SAd0xyfllHJ0U6B1cjkWwmLy@5H9wTyU0OsA7ZbNYp7TweMO9YmCVly2@Jf9gnZO1fx/Eq0@fbW46Pp5lMstoOLNbjYq1@QXsIklX6Ktl6u6E2//RH9FWCrSRFyueqVXWD8Rctp1WrueCtWKpWS8HLeiJRvn7VM1tqARSCXC6ZrFbhZSsAm4HXEGwJwAYveYBqeHrH54Lne/tkrx@4RD6GH8rgbCGRoa994Iej4mJFvHMn4X@Qems7eeeOVs5cXIQ@oxF4qQterVbXdFst9M9eXIgtkXablPPwnildXKiZckqNJx038QS/OAZZJSSVfaTVKdcyMF8tV0z@w@gIACy/uVnI1euFHLgLJVz3vn4RNZi4Ho@dB0N2MclZY3xdEatc5YTe7eHFzi9jVO0sl08mgLkmQXi7jOEf91bLZe6fZLlCopQq@3@1NdCcQRThfyhPZVO5jeLGXZBL8W@69EKeXD03aupl7dyo4Hz3ZbXjf@8Vz8kbd@5ky0DWUqZ6LLRa97ePtlutmiiKKM7ADT2Juwv4mbmRG29QlefLzQaWsHkcj1eqd6l5qKU8g3bgx5PiMEywUpkIIZg9NIIBpRe4PrPG1gSNnngTypySa@AJ@gZmjb8uXKzL2qyPF@vjzCUzmUUXsxgPp3unE0Zy@OWHhq@UFq/QxwgvIfb00fbO7lFa25RYTHuwvZPWDp/di6n4mp@/U3AW3w92t@/vP4METx/tbh/ufrz32e6zp@DvsbP5FfB5/z5/Rl1L3s/Yc@GV@0Y3DN2YGEbrbDI5e81emWbLhPqzJlAIp@8yz2gB7iN9Xo4q/Dqmp796pbsjuti7H3zr3Q/@u3c//M67H37r3Q@/99Mvv/ct@P0Yft/hz@/823Ie7z/98l/87rvf@SF4/kf4/RH8fvLTL3/z6/xH738Mv/8c8ftj/xeJx38CwPqVn3753R/99Mtf/T78/pX/@/7136/9ZPnve99c/cN03/3dm@N859/B7/c4rCDud36H@@HzWvzf4fF@9fvvfuPf8/8/9f/Q@cN3v/HHePNf/vn3//Q/v/vGf9C00p/@m3ff/O67b37j3Te//e6b/1R795v/Rs1Eb7/77nt/8Fd/@Ht/9Yf/I/3/mO6/9z7/777/z//if/2L//0v/tD//QR@/x5cP/mL/wB942//4Af4/90/@Ns/@gH@/8//@m//4Nf/9lf@J3L8Fnf8P//q3/L7X//af/qb3/72X/3k63/z6z/5m9/6g7/6P371//rN//TX//3v//U/@wZ6/tZP/uqPfuUvv/Gtv/zmv/zLb3y54v6tG@9fvof/l/8IPu@P5/vAeZ9yfajPlz8XPn8fasxzgXYCrfuX3/3mL0ED/w3G3n3rx3ioBH4r/n@sqRTnx/zt/wMO7XqZMSQDLvj9@rtvfQdJ9D8AieA/pNe3w5eFEP7y7fkLkPW3lyT65Z9@@S9/RG8xo1KnJRQcrktaKbUBKs1GuewP2f7qCiT5pUVoIQA/p28jh1oI@zbytnc/@Pq7H/3Tdz/4rXc/@BUcMKVcOb2dltRbpwml/HvEw4iF94mHET/H/FM0ASalPoc39rkf@PnnnwutCwVPL929AN/PyYtfjAfh6SY/KAhDfzzuxC5Y1O07M75z3fcNc2as8fJlExc/wQ9zT5HAsRFIQ/ksm6Z8xKaML7egP0SabpBzinfyxeCpgLf5/9w5FVgK4/ALv7YWOMnhp/Oz4E4hD9mkpuEiD4lnjItEG9yHFm0p31yZYQmm09QU9F5wQA4pCLqXYrVaLYUJaxwfeOWo1UuMUEmlalBuTM3TpFslBDG9R1AgZS11wFobtSlPmEJ49YAcKQG9DkRVE1Ol2n3IsDa9zxAWAiewL1/W6qXatI7g3nJ6pKape4QTAqulpvW38F4jmJBOiN1/C6iUaqlUvYQZYiF59aRbvJLyVDgqe4ql/DqAJ@6937rL2EeiWhJbXEpEgvHYeE/NY2NEiA7hx6kNvzj0Hzjpt0EEX6Os/FwYD98igXSLy6gYAeBKkizLDH64Gr7F7kLwlINKUbbwSHEIKWoR1AJCD4bTPykhRfWbohfIP1bb@OALgWFh1tfXhVhdzIr7MpFOUZh7UqGDCLg3DxWQChMLZRG9DTqVEeAC6auU/3oc17vijANmH6X47@7dDfYRFJOecz@BSamsk3NiHMpmKiVqAL/upIQXoIkI0E4J0IUgT2uk7KSEdJoxuRbDMLa/v@8jQR4vakIKmrmWVfEdV3kmk0kMUshyWk6n/adMT/KQfYdMof5TXkfi0pd7mablqqAwVRl6sah2o4IijJ5v376FWqHNTpU90FGZv@9Jy5UoEDy4EQfLmgWnd7RcWeD6OVMLOcYSNAkKV5IlBZZgG0mBb5HnSARXIq6VSnGKB9SXExvBNriCSs0BJ0BjdUQ0uLjSWMong8Cdfbaz//jx7pOjUbPJBIO@RGy0Rq7TMTwvgWHbT@7z4xFauZCMNRoI@qiiIYMRdisZYsZ79w/2DiuMF9qvggQhVqXlTr@YZVWIjUbPN2P@NiARv7LliId4r8zLltDKWUgaqwuxjoGaBa5jV2n7R1V47PXvOVNQ/dOimFYLqM4ladqXCV9zJgxtQHKDEdCn8NCEvLlJFBDq5xKtKaATaqsg1Ov@BjqmCvXD3SNIcLTPVC0jC/XP2VTGDKVLoW7VLMPujwfruBNNPM6IkTKtNzJp/NOyWbiruUJazReba2vWuYR5HlO1neOWwkt4PZewGF@BiwlfEdhXwAsuyAP3CTJ/k@beftXfKYfWlhJ8u5yo5qGbJYVjqGgOThjNL0AUWvfiCo0QW/viizGr10GllvYeCDHgFgMWbBaTzK48kKmauxPXoNA@Y13zMxM/nyZ3TW9k6TPoOkCN2OXlZQ8g7T1gWl2jV56ii/fLDvm0wX051YWYXanU3qq5oqCdVCpvs5omgIewoeButDVoALS8v6Hwv6oHmWSzJQU4lSqK8MhmswJODQtCxRAY7dx4m6nVJN4GszmVNm7gFIGiT2taePlxpx/N42YzPC6GQADrj12WCcKKPMx/Kwj0BkTDrWr0/deq3zkzd@5kcd4im8uEExRUYnYJdbOezWWR4sL/fy1etPSyOapnM@qmMgKnDs7cpqKDsw3O/KbSBqcJzvKmYoJzUs@qmU1lUheYsMkNLzK061ATx8YU7bxyP7HuGVZPxhM/NZEy0MRN35BxPUhY79a6Toc@1lztyiZ@NBuPY/IEuZxYdWw0CVZD4wB0gJUlkudCv3ZGh0YFo9aX0cqEa@uW0JXbTncme@OZhWdnLMetxUEujAcBc@gGCCQ477WVzeYqDdaUR85oS9DyxVRDzcBIgj@1lNbSa8ZWsVjpyh3L0N2tfCVfSnfxWI6/HrWVz1T68uePHz0cj0cHBp3V2cqVIQHaZUILKlulSj7fbDREMdWgbJr4DVrOp6S1Nejcht6V4Nlz7LEnaaUmJO6abq0Wj29lVU1SK9lM6VKYEw5pjiWsC5g0hSVLI93PfVZQsR0buE4lrafNc6JCpdfrXW6cp@Yvgn4u8Tegz6Wkp9vn4WtVisSrsElaMueB4KP3gNzn/kJcRdTyJbHaqM7fiwWx2rwU7g6NrqnjEZ3jzPn1VAXgzhxqDDI6ZsJlxXWccaVt9BzXmEfMqoUgIkfoeoSceBlmd5zBHM@vZ1eIRJqeX4eSy4uXYaoALeHyEujOiQ39ghvVrNNO1oZazjV3gRU1mpuBuU2sm9iLF7per0Mln@eKWi6fy2vZQiFf1GDIKecK@RJ0s0whk9c0AJArl8rFS2jRQkzXpXotq2UFTZO0rJRVJTWL/7c4NPx///ga/Gt4h1RZTThCmxVPYCyD8ddmj/Ds@9hhRw5@/aTP7hmdFTF2Bjrt@d1xHc/7e8S5p9snPOi@yQ1FhkEPdfwElDc0x4MVMZ6NhmjuwnD/0SDsDtuAILImHuEe3FzLcZZFKLJnT1eU8nFomhmIwW0zQ/SDvY8fHkWeR7vbOw@FAru3/@T@lUfej5Rnj3YfHIWvRR4aJM2HIL62@@jR1Vf/kdt/dtCbOC7@hAf7z3LzW@iFR0qFHFyLkUJvAuLf8JWkPZzhX2P5YuBQBTyIcAc01ju@M1@YOzPofM7Py5peuDGeH52uCEfBIVqdIddrG6zDrZqgCk0Wx3wBWy2WBWHEbOeMFTOs61iWjt@z7q2B50DHA4EGSpkWfY4dsz5zXKt7ZnaNNeExnj0sq/jtYERCeAhAhpMOmfcBCQPtV3bxS9O4pNS2Jgab4FfeV3jCA73Q6Zr9AYyHZ04QQWjrOoPfh16Q3ohe45s9xjwP8rsWYl2PLsQEUXyoj/W7sRIwcK85qmcqlTt31KeuWM6KXt/YnUKDZc@gA@nuLF0Sx7L4gMmtWB@XGqyCms85o7peB92gAZI0DKNbOc2olzL5v/7tH//dn/x6WevX1I3j@HFmJ/P4Ub4C3BGES0byoy9jyqRtaOVSvlTOaqV0qVzK5dVCPp9WtTQoasUyyOoZtaQWSvmymi7lyiAT5MoQmi8XfQlVCURSZaMCYO0Ofs12kxQWeQCaCV9EZG8SepLF9PB9wkQD0ogC6oZjOl69YdZgOGNqhmWLDCDqrMNiDx7sZB48EMV7@IKbJ3YyotjFl3wpkyneE0WDQnZKKN@IDk9TQrtg4pi/ZDL3dkRxwgGgSW1RHODLbgFnuUTRxJed7QcPMJ8evmiYHqKd8BD@YgUvRYhm4wsIzgTgdQgNom3zfHKE6C6@YJYY8oCH7ECYKH4coIMhBzwaB/AwKOn2tiju8ZftbQzZoWLnOaKf4ss2XaLowgs0flHsg6PvQrcTxTY4sQuIYgdcnZkOfvjlYLS6bI91UZxx8iCBRHFKsfXOiSi2An/M5jMfmzxSt0IvKi/1XXop458oagHSGC0bvmRFMRe@5KBsDx9@pg/GXaPPr5nLnx0o6cOHWd2cTnYftD/@uN3vt93Z9u7HBxi0s/MQZIPZxG33237CdgsuB1LtPNT0k@Hs6gWl3mu1Krq1NOjTViun21eCWrOWgRhCqteAmX/1MaNhaweCdh627urLFnQJYAt7/xCebbzuDeF5T2/zoOCiIHpO222xis0fBXdch8WeeAKM1E4P9Y7rVPF9WltjLJ6Ip2eNQqZZpQA2BAE8U73E8F4C7zrOxiTPZ41pLdOsTWtFjW8G6iXE46mWN8X02nBLLecra/qWquVS0woad3B6cRaX1C2WUO9svGGJJ8ktDYRx8XhrSxIbanNLU0uVQvHFxkQUkxW8b2WLFYiYiWcYw1uyUWxuFfORJMViSle0SrGYrF4CPcYwnLdxlqSVSJwZ@kkyieiizg5FoLKyGZXTrPYS0/S0xvFis2R1WlOr3NAoy1yD1UWr1pPO2HE5xD6Am25lKrgKnhDVckmE/BUlkUyiMk3asiLM90o@/@rRydHR58AJmVD35xKe8o9wV/3Xjx/uyHv7wRtao5YfoALkuPIOsquFEG4sOfA6AlVAfgjjJ6hVgR8eoXMdS96ddowRalFBQGBjVPYtQ8pHDxfgHA6cM54zWiCoknkxu2MwNNZtdpleq4NL77IEYcX05BmN3K16vdaqDemQPhQxSPUpI0vWczB7Hsc9tItAyc/xWJkf0KplLqvt2jQ2BTitGpPUl0On@1JLdapdtNF9r3YPE1db8GxXjZrhuo4rxsRqb8uuMTaxPb1nPDVctPixt78OcgSeNUv0mJFcZ8e7GHsHFYZLqe4ye47Zk8kwARJ5O7noFXlF0iS@GhT5nA4/4iaJy2qvxhIvktXX8Oqus0RXvpfcylW7iXuslQSfzMveyx7TWCFXpY/nJhASdCKiDZZZT9bqn4LowwGfVCqAiF/HJwATcwKwZpcC9OTIvKx2ahZLSGzKkkSeXLVfa2DqC7xtSqLYlKTGRVOoS9JzoQ79tDqL6TVv0qYPO7BMW9UyheoU/NRirjqAitVfTKtubTRxjaoFr/7EGj/jqVeBnEA1APPmIvHul76e3JTyNe5XJVAXFkgbLblVm1ZtNBUHTaKWrUFAqpHLpEGJhlsxDcO8VkirhXQ2nUtLRfSFMT6dT4MnKDYgUySshMiYmM5MM7KaVg01nci8NLsvk@mTBAgrRDKWTI@dXXsyZOADlYStkl7hqbNkStuwGNSCw/RNiZopcIoqFgxoPmAjMz1AUAeGblGKZFJi2Y2EtZ7AOOtHk9Fuo1mp7E5HX4WghPR6q5AqZlJvkslqYi1Z84zXQr0q1JGrUKlHa9Bm/TlH5k2GDahjcKlFrdJotLGIxUw6m8lC6czWRX9TrIvNdGatoEIVXTISjxjnGNFpOBRy5n6jFgrclgFVp5a1qiDTnFi2pEllJb@Rz/B5OZ5SGPlsDSnJEsdicJ45EY8XtXg8Ga/iisCa6E8BAy8jPhYHphq/o26JIH@JFbGsYYQ5S6Qjq5kAO5DALgWcf2C5shA7Fy7PLzdBG1Zo/yRIjGyNXJJcvyvEKoyBGHjsW1BS1hj70G2Zqc36C/48xl3zAFcgm64ggtJ2KcNEDYx9hqfzt1gcENPdYUPTss2GVoSBDJhjEBX08CougsRwW75cBwp754DfZqqOB9s@ZbOZnpKCWfk7jPVT6wKVOXZ1wXO7tt0/2A42g23v4ETvMYjYYjUuxs7jsfgl/Amxu3SaTuOn6Vgscp6OT/T/QvxuLB6P44w6EOptjHgE2zkPJsAq@ImxhF7hHKHRTL59YlrnpazE5yWARV1extYVXO70VyqyuUKyTDUVnG/69KUGjSRmO4EHqEY4hQSDVz6Ps9cx5eXI@0IrZR/v7dv33QcG48edSrmWWI@xjCrhqaFqxffNi621ExXaSFbMnqRj7G6Mdp@L5ZImatyjGmMnUlyt8CNSo8Pyi@KL0ovHz/af7T8QYsdrF2sOLlSwcDPdW/uTr0LEeDYXZ@y4FpvWclV/K129LqmbGhoxK7IKsP@eWpAyF3XezOsUUNAg5N0vfT833SzBu5ZR4V3T8imtXlc3NJaMjd59@ftoj@Z897PtRyyO09t/9yc/0op/9yf/mranxS9pylvLFmMQE51qoRg7Px@dn1/CxcPysWaMI5UrJsHNl1/UWF1Rtaxt21VWUXR9o5jKaXftquLHVYtqMuZJMX8hqZiPeRd@kJYpQVCw0kNeYgGrJLZ7YOY19e7mFhRnK5vTqmvQjNTwUCYL/zYNrxwTYqXHLy8Yg5dOvdvvmxq5FIVV3kps8620yd7iKstbaY29rNVxtV7Fo5zBKsQGHnLDlbh4PaVsxBmoRazeuKxeNlO0kAEK5AvD2LCPr3SC4zU857DotWHDn7Hh0R8mCjw8eA3ejI1XnpjYSCpKtxsaPds0WL4OrWJDAdw2gqUI/idJx8l3v/Sbmlb4uz/5tYvWRetzDRTJcrmgarGf/WxzYk88o1v/GSS8wdBIoAzSOg5aBEFHqEQybszS9FOFDrkD@uvERqmZxw9USlQiUeYw@7bRJZVSOEU5iSqyxW3ddRMUbQPtEKRJ6ibbUsmqIITSKUnVbr@TJhhsA60dQk8XzoWvYBAMxqwGTFj4yhwUeAxh@HU6Lc@auCM6FZKgdGozze5AEsjhK2hGcI3sJ/icXALup2xcT8pR9ohqJFOxoeF5aJQQBiHhK5DEtwRrzdhIR1MfGNO0YeiQMQrhSQHdBuTdhLwtnqBFvgkqPY@QZhw7nsgGyVv4CggTRAUTZAxmbkKEKrClrwABoAwJH7DZZJssm2TnZipVnVs8vMSd8WiTUQ/MDAiYDKF10axFkLiK8cALJH789iC2C7@GQbyLeAZAOAy@ql4DnQGT0xsKbWQH5L1BASyyuZWgorE7d@ZY1WpmN8moRAj/xBzhdBfVg70cVwAW6FsfdStimqEtyWrgGzY7oHiK0IVWJ3EjktVIUibi66UgwP97N1pskVeqigKqWAC/vniv6ADJIDGSnddhh23WmKoVkyxEvgO4dwgpOu0dKpHH049k7fMg8BIw/Fks@LIHsKij6BSi326v2plgMIhO8LMKaG2MMwPfPgS3J4asbm8cpA5TQVFMi2L3TBcUHFruD0wZJrJqEpPNTT8SHrTfXcvhTnEtn8QHpcLYDJ46muTz81kjU0IdByrUGzk22fAjG0O4pR9aBPAo3/wZR3tin@FnePy6ocRRjDwyfYYtHzEmm4T0/WJKi@vtbRe04IA2aWb0ZdYZdplWZglqaGSmzQ7BJSkRIdwGaRlp3LaMIaB0aBh0SsurKEofhK1Jm2zVPTahXQ0emDDe2J7ifypaOTNPTOUIPyMgOT08zMUtf8RQPsPux5f2fbtwluOcMMs8MfjMcGLBborHQF8AkTcNlJ3/gLAV3DOiZdMsA8FpHgt@RXgUubOUjqRdS8yS159ZdS3Rwhq9oMHHdPEz0Ke6HaEvXReCryJ7My@wvET2g@BdDlmu4dtcqcXRmkJoTEjwbUjVyHyRjCsOowQorIHtJXQKI9c4ZajsCjjGANPsBFZMsBdDab9CAwD1PehZaJJx7FbQ9g5g4nYTHeh6PoO32UcsqwkYkRvG8o1YAQys@toidAiDpFgOb9yFipFpmh35CvTOYRfC0OqD3/wwfdC60U3mMufNm6354HDQobxqjHeL4CUfecHege2Zir4GgQXAcAkmawkxBWBTYlLkoMP0V5Pz1i4QL6mw65DSDCH4pAYoJCoE34lnke/lCBBwT/e4UXXfYOPZ2ZlMVkQnrikbHn5DxnNs3VJGfRMkakcZG8OR/7VOE7/S7MOduyT@6Sh5NBhtTVF0rZXvzPhTEHpezd95k4j3vDgOjqf4iZT@kCyOoakvjxrUA5M@r9RJ@BuBePvTmunzoP1VsP1JpfglAmEMwUzTs3QnDcDS7c5JunfWrfoBp9QhATjUohF4om1fN3gZeoHLHPXCGM4Y@WgY1LZOaA0VIIl8SneeNS9hEHMWvPrvI3MKiWzjjG27rj5LUHgSY2MDTsxI7GEzGPYpBJwwzLBzbmjWnDZmzYXk0zA5DGrhDgIXzYkJ5zcD5VaHMXzKw6cQPuXh03mmQbaNaZOLZOh1icXBVo9WKIOYCGYWxLnkFnrnIQQZpG@mchAYc7bgdwm/To1SB/Tmb1CPtaBhQJsYAcGNhNJ4cdw4btqecbbRTCl9aOwiEQJqHEA3mkTTs27oRupbp9bI8Ra8bDQ@CqOSjzd6dQZ@a@BtBcsYVhA1DE4vE@1F9of@VgcuEPgFBggoh0Egigbb44SZrIZWrikQGk5DnNOYI9bwkWmS9OUH@X4gLnHSc8JGATUjgNA/LBKgCSEs6Dn8i2EBd3juOhAniCvRR46GaLcs3owDJa90Fc5rqlRJEawkKUATyI7iau1qUYJwqIrGlaBIMS/9@o@iv/bB6PegXyzHnhosHzCqQrSr4DZDECH87kJUZfVapF4BA2VDtwwXRq5dLp/6ozVks6EEagbPB4vgneFn0BORyu8kef3QkUbRFithU5jValDEWY13S94vApJygofJPD/ZLGgIfnrOQABGZmkyw082jSab1mqccbDpimRnESSnhOSUJ@GxpyuQbPrJQHvaC4YXrJ4mSKe4D1IEeCofRkEMGokMv4WOi@Cv0KYirp36ec55DrUCvw2hiI3trNNcmnsjgnSEaV0BgA3xGoAu//hoRbjK8FQpfAt5FCdlwKP4m98MOK@ABkYsuMrtDifCRkY6MAj8YorGAei7YqohiCrNC@Nfhv/EdOAZ/NTrnpnFmOqiZyZ95e8fxbOJlI100Ij0oWZyyJBRk3lm@wY7ozJHDL/TPXBAqmufOSyxRNgGf2XiJ1XaltNWhjpuZsFPEnJfeTRLBvoDrqmwuyNnrI@dXK7ClSaTmt2y/LnOYPZtB79kErE9DrJe1zE8Oz6GSu04fdv0jDRDs5Anhq92GP7HEISonOw7HU8Q/BlNrsYiaN6uUNRttfAjya1WAncOJivhfmjaSIjNMx4XUP8FVyQ9sCcf6P4o4bRfGZ1x8naYaEjfT3Zkdk4S@yM/EGdftxnwsA7I/xA6AAmGec5ccyQj3ShKt8cJ@pzHwBk6fZD6Jp4sYOor4PfmsBEhfTQiXNJMR5W2EvmcAvWSRCetJ/2kn35wUvapltCTYXptEcACMdLMvUpjpKy7JLvWyux4siC/ww/H9zCK7@HN@JIWfhVnrprXeOCHZZ1NzCFAxDka2dvRwKID3@peQ2cBldAb5Sqe4L1R7NJmsS5iug1Rt/3ocg/aRzp88@AtRPyzVfS/uQKD5LvvW306fjn@cAb8ZoibIBP08SkvWBxNQPS9JPKe69mFTfv@e@YFcfG7fw9QhAAxlhiXjfaFoWOOQO32wuniAPAtbR73Z11r97Rpq8YDl@DknqbZiba6iu63uoalz4xuwo@ZjsANSnwAChvxq/crODI6YnoO1/USMHYlw1AYxpHoPFJlRZPR06fJ5OpmxaOYYeuhmXLCcG81/TD8GmvGKb4an60GPSAej@F07KmJ05@j2WjGTdhb/BNEPh/l4w@vSbTbcDtBgA589FTT82yTN7HPg0RYpPcYEcK48mKR0cJ0ABFtEV2vww8j0e0lhcqNJKoFtSwsfrxleY2bN9V4pFUEbZKvMr1fk7yt0b13m4s0NQ5szsJ2PmwIuQYZ93N0OokoRO5zY4059jWegH40T2evGFVaSxhqmJI43dgkdZvki6SAmvEePHHC6TN4IsC@MW7xBhWUDee0/I/5MQoZ6qOI1OL7gJAOUCJU5CT30YjEEgI3RD@/DPPsrMyzcy3PzkKeYQ9YzDISSegsZOnXAlbPTVVgGb3xCu6MQag7w@Mmtg2X7eguzlacx814xUyz@Gm8Agw5bsQruwlgyvFuvHKfHF68ckiOk3jlU3DM@1b8Il4JugVGcOGVHHfR32fh@N6JV3YSyUthrJ8YXpCvHK@EdQpxtvgrUQRIgeUGqRGX2GzHL@bYNWBgI6EyzbDFeGlUn2geJk2/DPzzzzHRh1owEOc4NygySzF1YdCIjBg8Hxg2gg8BLOnJFX80391/QPuhwiiYTQp0vGgaAg9ieCy@yIw4YhhKKxrwBASRb1aWY8QiI9l7ouPnDi2UKnkxf6KeTPJAN0HhDYjcnGdC3@Dy0wf1tQiCV@D74YmJV@F5DZ0gO8II12STS9BCor6M31AorOtFXPzaj9YQzXUvRgJspSAKryUCG@HpIMPR4hxmNnJGi42EQnHLvRlNQ5NyvFNi672SjLiC3zNXBJO3XzJkDNHOn7ypOJF0iNoCC8LARqbJe1k4LhAvxqA5r4tIqrzzAQoRngM93Oic0PfN7vtOisfZTZrGilXDUJCWZ0mca5FNQmIZDWFN9DHPPVRed9E81oepr0HKKc61JBBAJGWYC@evzgfI7w6X3wOBOiDClQyWCdbLh9Lr4vWNo@wVzK15ttcrEAPT7H5yqXAU5jAnOWgHEcn8prZ2TcTHLR9cyOeZhtCvSPsB2UKd4Ba6XdUtOCyUEtzTRc8TDTxPtNWEui6RWKdyILTImJMPhxc8xHRetJtx5QVfVsUYQvPbuvXBFewuVnC08hAeFcC9QnLey92JTbtc5n0b2Db3QZaqVhhn5LRcGlbz3BPYPS3dhsu24LHfOri//@TR12DQLRaLSX@Mns3xw16Lc63hOM4h0@bqcDxYorZoafwIES5243S8N3Dc8dqxLV7jJZxZgzCgQy5B8/P7eNLnZRF@fqXvQjoeN0JRH9bJvBvoC1wJRR0dh2zTp@sYCGKMExu6DyQQb4HeadLWkvS5nVbL1odGq0XDV6uFm5daLX8Uw6oJVsSTP4utKRPPpY8B829FnQkCWXpg9/fZ84fbR@zo4S578GznU/a1/Wfs@faTIzzk//TZvUd7Owx@u08Od5mwsOsSv6uHCiXQ9b7RMfBjqUzLZHLs/y3uWrfaWJbzb@Yp2hI2GhjdsMHYQtgChK0TDD5c7O0FWHuQRjB767Y1AiTb7HWSH3mB5H8eIa@Sd8ivPEVSX1X3XCSB8XHWOl7LaGa6u7q6urr6VheGvNXrj0XuZLZs@X7odtTbXsPDNdV64HZeX8pLrusNN6RUlbajY5xh@hxHseMPoW/Bgf9oG4vFTZPNBGELoCjvOe1pO9jzdnpNv@VTXgt7377vBcayTLV96kGSt8bQ2ZFFEmL8seoQx@6EBtYNFXcpP@5uCIwr@lcgMXJIUMBmTmnChf9@mIJH1YN3hwr@Irb297ZrR7X9vUO1s39Ar@8/1fbeED1rh0cHtc1jJHHGd/vbtZ3aVoU/CAKFnIIjh9@uguG9KOSQnanS@B0337k@dX/4ljz1xgpe3bhsMBmohasupI/vtv0vXnOhZF0FWL7ASJOvClRmvnLw5gPN@cr7Azec5iqY9Q9SxwHHnZwvqHWujQbLBo23kmU8NGayRZvvIzpjhdAzXokdPGT42VEGOCvxNH1Ppbago4Kzb/EDwWPZgKaKHhFsgDIKK2XFIaMWFpx1BrlBtTXaPbjulNpEiVC/oOhro2pSsphiWlcGQGHvUOviPKhYCj8Q39OHZV3tcCAZ1NPwg2RQz@QDlqI16I6oFZ3jarh/BfGsVuXDb53@Dl8Lq@fhh02Xd7FrGifpN@5SV4Uh9@AVo82BweSUh4OXukHD97lIwPkRNKvdloHhSbhGkolylci6bZQzRcKmhasGrfYmUZCRStwAPSG3NQxUpmzn1BGUg7yuLyHZLtpuV1SgItUd5j21BgdE5Q29fAhDmbEFSb/HDIgwikk8wnLbelXoPbQcldycqtHVOpIcTtSooH0Pgc0pBP4eMAQom9jpNHimYhtWgOm1NCtngh5xJM5t/4znJ3ZuXjW8RAGttZX5zf/yxdZEdhL7JKOnyNhRF33xBrSs5KvMVm9AY5zFKgd/ghRsXPb6Q1/6MJNsAd848TRHuTGxUW2/GuLq2kCHyRq7vW6s0nPi4jtqPSemfEitzPFydx6KrygqMHE@TcKidwd03PPetRe7O3NwiXTj4fiFFsJ8V47Dz/GQMZH1pxXJjj8VgomulTe2N0@zf/7qIKKoiAUJ6GuUDvGfGBN10fDgez5WWBxg3aVHmokEF1ydo7TWwdPSEqPcAKN94KVP@7rX9VKYJurG099hYzP5nT9@@1aWUllIJh0FOrjMRNLNUSemSofLnCmtAhKTnYQsyfqM@eIwzFBev4ZdDXoBHnW6kCPYt0/EWdMixLTu/KpFkkWHu9XdHcK31QZrVESxwmEvE@@P/OfMZnlpw85HCiUqRs6MEdGOgVy07ZhaCs9XU@C27wdH8vvh4NbuxU6mhx@Ctn0vtB/CLbt0NyyZlmKwHg72z3vAyuT2d4Gltjt3A5ZJchpayOkhczrz6VCb9v4af53qOx57BAZzL05QQqCx2q66fEVtPGVnpIAdBxMtiA6PtqsHByol@xMqS3IPW4amFoOA/Ui9j7Rt/S4Lu1y4aIq7t5bFk/mS0Ggz/@4bzDOJd4eo0GsQR9MjFBZR4J6WPxKpp2cWXkKw9j0LREO5JHZfjQwKTjTgW9oDErJRp8UaaM1sZlomHz@IK4FrujmyNo7r8LOGtczdCCI7GMcBxXWC3AtYlszuv4@yPn5p6pEFFrwPocFNWknTfEP7hEOquE8Zc7lkD97TLaZLoWQvC@y0oR0UvwrJFfbPMxQzkizCZS0cE@t6caxRk/XxvFnmsEIipgEXmp46UTSaKcGIeP6yHu9QO5r0MskpiBaZCCv6Os4VVPzsVk9hTI1wniyHC/L4WJtnbE4Mlmc4ndWwS3dnegxd6NVJ8TBZFUnbe6vK/v9UJbNEoiZD85mNMYkEeXVl5en3YE@2whTP/ixsmUMm5eew06f9fQQyGAd8vE@cW9tzTHrEAPeQTlTrzYCZKEhLnRlzSqLtPBnF8SNc5FyIkIHfeERqnazVVqMJ3GZDlxkpDp2zTLUhNoTDhsqomaL@7f3VQSB/t75HP16fDDZkgurgLbTy3/UGgRdZ5cV8u8Q@wRo2@c0bDLqcTeyZOoCSYTOme43t2NpOFF6lVUjk@7Z4S1raOknUbh1z1sCV8PFiDsGZcbpXmjzeyxZL8abu1HarapH9SLYSZ5GpQcqOyZ5Hfvc@BFgG87kEpg@24XscvKT/hINjQBKZ2Jovw7Sxv4sbU4RWzSccN0irhWrZWpzs/VbQcLtwCeKkHgcq5TyhgnwKW93fsWedrBdKifKEXNDvZqiUk8rmUlyUvuFAF5CSIKQ38T02YcFSw2hKwrzmogf9KFxseSM5PWPNSTdfXCusvrC4dV1n6HROXpw5i41yStHk63Y7wdXgpvn7Re/yuqXaqv/b@agx/vKHUivP1FOqa/mJOPMtrpbz7D/1Of1dUy8KzLkawVfsmBjBgnMSRVWpBRXtw0uPlEQk4U3zS1hITHCpWuwYLoSJ3bDcOVk9K3fLhVLnpHtWgpHfcKk8XCouZfDhCc2iJGPkZv5keIY5NX7q6nWvFVxmctxObRqi2DSEvrxzB35vt7L3JnEahwUAjsC0rjcfqEtg5jlos8H2JNf1bjL6mMxR4FgLCyRrjq2CijCV5/NkHMc0fcKMesWh1Www4r9j25or5K76wx6nGL@IYC31zf9mzRkzpgKfKFCWE994T4R9AcGJ8mRwMSRfx6JFnS3Kcq0I20k7BuIEJVkcpk5TKdgUAlFty3VyZgU5z21cAglEIv/GxdT6OsclJ1YLcnyKB1UOd8AGE4UzPOIChH76fNuAKnjlHrDZh0XNx3sRD/KFz6iGbCfDCvIWrxSRAvVv9ZXtm7j8OhFACD8na66cPuLUKy9aSIrtIB8uwNFZcuOPawaYVUqnzKGxgC31lSPgrCnONEK1mkz0fe4G5BRa0T/dgmyR36aaEea3JTuThO@p9VsAWnKXctIGftpRsUysWNYUM5ljpJj7LjVw0kXbo3ceDaux2vLabUJaaDEXkQOPbN@r618K6w9OUOdZiLykZ6fSs4n0nKQLUlGuHE3wUaaX8Uyp9Nco361KRdmcqbrKihcvOerpRo6WJFHe0n15g9ywV/ejzBthVwpXhgnriYRsLOXzjN6XlEeJMiGDh@knkq75e1n3fIhlIu/rZP34tXQHeaw8q3VNJrg01/XbrywdxFqngM1SRE2lpDhHLFRmUJW1DaYWJ7SCwzk/D9uNcgRlqWgkDo@Z1Mb661ROLzJeZSbRECvGqYE1Y4zEqMR1LjHhRmywSPVw8qMYCIYJRlNm5G6YwmNdeBwDi1yPTLViBTk1wKlpk0O8DLvIb/hjBnsSOZMvPTtxTjAfSePFujlJIBa6j1KzyZSUJjAXkY@6UffMIlHd40mIs4XEXuwUOKzTExvsFo7BH4VyIi4ojKSYonuYoikdZSga9r2rC5F4a/1vftF649Iau9/2RqqCbYbLVlhWwsB96AXDAL6h2MVNcNXvt3HryAu@Gzah1m5Flldw3RJBjM3sOasGzR7J7@BJG6RToZzaB@QbKIhECcHVxQWMyWAB27uBaMWJiz/MWZXuWA40aMw8XRYzc0/B@QYL4LZ/EUdCek5GDygd9N2Gl7NojRbQ6seSprZ8HemTz9NhNwLvYzSlvbSsv175jd@33uA@93mx8LQYI9m1vg4u5J4@iwysiEgmYRmeA1eKzywrdjfckLvhLAA6ahcT/QfiTe/a63Y9q0IzBmcMaNEaeINrr5mzrAMvvAQGXLAybiZhh927GjTkcIcWXS4xI6yEA0euw4jD8Iv5Wa6LG3xX5li4tIpum6mrr/0mCGgsTlo93A7zhQXcBAg9UKjjDYkoi7ZKosR3zxoXXrt0cBBF1ICfk9jdREiGbm/oN6hn@CTLahMouQaJKus2JzCh@hptF8bBuVkIwDwmooBBwFwl3YeDpS/NfwgHpRtm7thd0zN5kn49His03L2BT9I3IjD3CheL4U4dfPS2dqgO93eOPlYOqoqe3x/sf6htV7fV5ie@48ZFOXvhVW/3d0m6hLfpcmu@Tx9SlUMqmeIEq7L3SVV/eX9QPTxU@weq9u79bo2gEfiDyt5RrXroqNre1u7xNt@@EwS1t3@kdmvvakeU7Wjf4VpNMSsqp/Z31LvqwdZbeq1s1nZrR5@4xp3a0R4qw61@Rb2vHBzVto53Kwfq/fHB@/3DqkLDrO3a4dZupfauup2j@qlOVf1Q3TtSh28ru7sTDd3/uFc9UKwkEGvlZpWwrGzSFhY1cTu3awfVrSM0KHraIuIRgruOOnxf3arhofpLlZpTOfjkaKCH1b8eUyZKVNuVd5U31Dgr8x2qUL9sHR9U4S0JlDg83jw8qh0dH1XVm/39bab1YfXgQ22relhS1u7@IRPs@LDqKIQ15KoJBlGL0ul58/iwxnSr7R3RnHH8HvoONnXyRyIMYVmhottMYKhBoLVEpP2DT4AKOnAHOOrj2yp9PwBNmVoVUAEaFVtH8WxUIRHxKN5MtVd9s1t7U93bqiJ5H2A@1g6rNnVY7RAZalDI@ESsQ5Uec6vRT4SXPBKzWoZzHe5OVdtRle0PNWCucxMHHNY0tzDZtt5qmufgozd2iOL3cGbgduIHK63pT9cenFNOn8jMPqMJPSZt7W9XaUbWrq1SUcIxzTprE66U4mk004SJ9JpwWdP0zq8u6n631YONaVhMDj46wYWDyD02wp6cWvcEsNLnK1wgna7XP1TqtNE9rNdt5yElE2h8r4Q@Br8vl63biGgI2Hnj4OflS6H7eoJQG0/0RScr6uECAjmF@k9E9c3teLbK55ueLgbjfQA2R0eBXJtc4iqFRCMbOyJeS1Qln0zwu6/ZgQtmDPhco45zUmhGcqZeQH@636IXmRxiH0g6y3FXPo9NLKPhf/FMNVIJu0TgP9ojgd/iKnOB5/1@kSnEq8OeP3fR6zUztm3KcN4h7QMvMvZ3ip97FxPFs5PlGVm@dtaBBAKz7@YlTHj/rEmmdL/kBtyyDP7Uh/xjG2zE5wNOTbkqPqzWh5aZJ1IcGkmO0q4tYF7BnYw137vKL7WP2M0Vlp@VJr6/Db/L2IK@IJzY0oR3wuXO@OftmWSgAca@OIgkvvaQkc/Hyhh9kzDzDWW8RKYbvwnNH5qrLz2e14kktJC9ctvxOjEbD/xRHHuSw28OKu82j3d2SHQC22drK89XS1bodusXR34/oR72NMtex/o0j9M6jZNio2SLFj48UmIeviP2ZwbO55ER3ttNp/FH@HkI9TaSmkwQZGhugOBFXajopTzQIaXYAccjy/DrzJGpGSCTaKqN1nTcES/xXVorMQ9oZZb2mHtthD@AHQ5/M8TDBmkG0izGvneJc2l3wXIvtWNURXlzw457kCWXMnwsbtxCGvBRF@vPwrqW3zRvx3oxEFVGjFfudi5JSDyaxEIZvYqujOz37GdEHwCz9zD68ovmN3r8pB3csbs7NxhWhodExp2wJM6po8No3egTDfkMkTTgVM3UtK5wym9rpHjs6ePk0DFIbDQwKgjTAh3fJOBS6EdkskrWgH29YKuvwqlw3gE4Jc2x@p04d1ZzNJSS8R@i341XCiWwQicnQrWbsA7LZPkU@rEw5EyQ6afowfD/gTSZAX@ddpwEPaJWzAnggyjJUIVWtH1lovg35qIhdrsRUTP@6VME5jbeMZdhw/TtzUjsa4gEunfG5sMndnvYyswgAJgcBxvx8RuqpF26tHV6nbJ1cdyTdBudfkbpucJMFVNws6tnDi@7HHO3ghdb2XLWFKtwl4qq17JxO@dRT1umia28ehykBJxt/H/kF/kAJBzwzKWXorU6yVkFPcqMHNCulmITTjP0mETL0ts7b@0WVcxFZkL265svQygCvQF8ptvJYUV6StRzkx4XeSZWR@wFD/7EsU3G5KNd1p2zImbbA5zHTT4MQeSR4Q0miLZAZ1d9ETSVecyKIqgk0jqM/AxC3No5Ii1Pqzch9nwyCQ4NsT/uiiN7T061TI6cOPjQGMbN5XPqnTsmlNsPa7awWH7xsOdAdxGVybGELo8oK41eb0BLRxftJhwdf2zn1Ed96OB1g6uB9l9I85k/0CcSZtFP1WDZJLt3nmbEhzyjFvhDWCs0c8wf3KSOBw1RcU8yyq6qDDGv4dENc@joj5aKKrMepawTTdgtKRNxXa2qb98klxBUuwz1mIJ@EG4uWGeT68G9Qzj8bnqD3zH3YwnUbXrN0DNpDCSfBUon1brs47ExlKb3ewGfaFBX4AQkpERRDtJCRVWao59rdtJ6TanIOyZ8l3JLfryekEmNthRVFDGurp2YbzVLnQkqLWvXoKGz0OLyCqMya8N1e@dmjL2FJq@tVeq0G4qUl7KIKD82S0c8idwMnz7hSR/ylx8HGD30BXfcegkKhLFmxb3qtJxj/KBT8NH3Bs34mSitZJpuH8dvvPXpdZkXzdGhdvvXcIeBN6YdQCPvj/IMo575S@@yW9/qtd0Lv@e7tE@DG/iRSDw8jvkRHXYx6N0EHECIE5qxTM1x9Cz@ZcQNG97De8lSzDVXMPT6mbiawnAwrlyKmwg@OYcSYBRRlPm7P@kjLSzzbCUqZCXtT1kfr2iX7iz7tDirsNzoA4AWcBsTGhRiQzpkw6SY8WlpKsP5fRliOJ6rrHLtOzT2Ehi/IBLxNUwCY4PMlFpCvBHYmd2J8Ulz5DTZB@EAjpa8bQ@hcIIMf3ZcBGkmKfIKmgIvVXGtECsqtygj@CHEw/huci8//wdjTwj8BPrFp7O4ZRYjsIhrGW9LgexXtJdRwoXVA32W0SyJSYr5F343Zn7IQShGk1CTyeO7qMGaP7Qo0m72prgSIzJDGx/EucvUSeTUxzYmlQW1YLPfDixBKsNM4W6G9b6nP8uDH5e4cnIGwbSlIWdiSN9FqgZRCWFwJ9Rr4yiLT@Xvj5jl5Yf22gQBy7NUzmLhmDMps3JhCxRf5ldca/UGJIxTE9TTqh4LwbDXX3gg9e6UHTM9s82idcO2v6sILMxWpslyscmkLY/xOC5Zk/hMME2SYqxpRjyE7Ss/h2w@ScRRuY7xVq6Pv0OHu2gW6U2Fk0rY300Z@5gUr6HRayaacEgx7nBSWgq/n9Sp4fW7JYiGKdurOkuMOkRGfSyPMVATZAqp9HAKMfdp3Cfo0STKod4m0S7eP3cSdVJJzrg8NUkJJ5egJxy3w2iT5FK/BeULuImTFW4opMIF58gZ81VeMXsOJ8NIEIBYFXvZ6BxKTnCjzprgI44O0MrUoS1UhCSip424hkPo9D8kGHvl14c7WuOhPs4Wz0oCaRRCol0F57oPkrE3p9eT@oihTJGChvgMUoQtmpJNlw9v1c@2hfIRBCnNyVrTt@CgMbZaImzoTzypPsIaOKpKl0yMqORAqLNooLFAu5SLtifbVaz@/IFwPLQb9DCiDYR8zuBnSZeAO@/VQkhtFBk1x8hia3LLaLNVdkOKRAwl7yC/Hoqy1OWNKwHwBGMqXy4SBLg1ZexxKcCud@Kcl0BU9xEVLBcxLOkje0WN9DxnpIOoOsOzlViOwqwcL@IwsjOB0MJidp4IEVqzzM4SQaGJbiYusRzPZ7cnykELYsP7QnHqCt0rSRqGPScE5LDPBTuSKCdF5RQ0B3PisxU7kRjyN6e@KMRSC5OpRJ8Qw5NscTJ1rZBITVS7vJwsmihJ9LDjtSYSiRR2HOFQKvzcPzZNibs8D3VCY5uMxCpD62cjLDftMmnflvstUOtslG3WGAZe3DLcbL/qEmIl4ZT9fgfsaoGvDOC7/adbazRTDSY6VgD7pTPGLhnZEPKKNYWpHs3CTtd42gsdFJg9ba@lPhzt7CTcvp6PjaJRxxusFAoFMPF53Pm90a3GUZLfyydz51tX7Xa@f/OXwYfzPMt@z@OQAC/NDtqjLqFBEeR6gwuJDAEcKCtyZ7UhK/b6V61WPAQDbijRedRtklN7Q1A8Afmh0suHIz4AYpB6gv0VDUT7flXh6LtxZaGpoZhrKCoNleDrlLk9I/LgQwv62eFNFQODYDbaTDRv2eWNr5hBENmEO4vdF9tfI/Xk1Fuv3e456iNCEMNTwNztZIGdnXiBgmTBDSNb914F7I/WUd61347ZFSNLnNcBzkxMJs6E8QsP3/gH3kV11M@kTj6naFqhJi@hmUvwT@2o1EXK1s7iHwBW@JDQflDujtvPNJhOk5lpqtcjOHoijJ4WnZl7n0QWm8/ENM2@nxtEnY1ujp01UNNtXgsYX/bcvdySO7KHxE2djoot0LAgMDRO8LnysBIwNfvHicXrYav1MKnIYQCkY39IIkoklJ8TiHwHwCNQDz@iJ7xo/1OWhvXOhEMRWeAgWMe03EGBOgpY1uNG@Y@bTKVSUfP9pSVVqWzSQzarKpsVtY0Pm5tqm9438f6kvLyyUhKZu21/pY@b5uOt2iQYfMK51LgcbNMrpZVhNwZtbXTxfL4875Tm6@X1jVKQP6lswqyfnv77n//1v//l3/IV/fIfeNnkl5PPYaZcLpefb3ydf3JbwvvJ9tnC/PnJfP9s4aIELvtf9hreqw2zbqQ@mhucW2mZBWJfWY/U7LPZ@4wuqkxMwI47@J2ky0uVbgT5tP4aSOQolrHphhf77sGO8py28CbowORWnpBIE9AxjuOpdxoeFPBoviFKEi7QA5XycrdiDu7hDibMEN6qpLUnHl6zXnuwaYk8KcAWl2asrN8NvC5OwK95zSvNsyyXfv1hXfNv/vO74GKzN1KLpxm1WFCLjlpMpfinuPqCvtrzeR/WuZKNtgOplEMp0dUC1AxV4PNCj/cPHGtngtyWNc8hewDJuKngzGIF54S7PzaWkYBrwYU1h1CcSo5I@JIJRdJf57u31C1fKcdtKmFqwwuFut7FcGWxG5Wwf7EEcgNRBIhq7ghBXvaoStz0sUUynvLmi@5ri6MJMWCQ9eDNDo97fKC5aL6rdZ4TeymEOWL1efmKubEkxtCMNlKk/ggBvlCR7WSBLQkX0guWaHnHWsnNFCvsePs084muw9gbGt10KfSnijGBaHPHCTff1XYtWpFbrldUyg@vV2JVpSZ1v5UVK9K5ag/9vjZX4NoxoL6Gtd3KSEKPMiCBIz77X06PMD4oMJ6iJrpFgmWNVbOHpstI6GrTdOpgOyc3RzEi5D9naGx/mxjbdp6tRAw7CA8wUqEqX8v124H2ujJgYl@4g3NEB3RbHFBtKPdmfJ6H6KsTGPdaIdI5hswq59F4pqak@wP3ouM6Kr3XOxq44xpNW7TyGTZyNrUQLpiABAafrnpW8wzC0iLdJUyRsCmsOYTgBe2xDo8mfZsKbU7QpWYoaLcrGAQJdmJKet8SfTVBx4irf6AT4ihPCe/wNlKLWJa80DTSkFJxsxkeZlNDxzI1xMdOOHBSlqAajkzDC7rQFSbaDl/8kiRvw0eArjulrQC1KcLqC9SP2enC67qJyanftoyhf76kZF7EeOZQlKKNZJk4qcUo4h2wonXk56QXCJmbjDsjay6TmTsNdDi3dHweYSffoS5@3lV@GICOA5ixZYg67voiLCdmqCgGRk7VWPOfILTa7gXhN75xx2DF03Tm1aO8ffL5tHu2mDntfjv9YjMmWiSbWTar0voy20gsPVZoZsw7iVejlRYYV4On3WSG064SG5YYCQiRfObkc/7sW54QOk0jJv1pWgiS6DJgkr@/vjzA56fQTCexyKetOXvRNp2feVW0Fc2t/Is@lA@2/BIWZlPJx/S0zxm0CBTb6f5xJSYnQX5tufBsufiMdkIX3ig78K4w32aDq3NvREuJANtZmnpOvyS4IUGI21HglujjiNopYU3E9iTQRkpahOphzvVYIVtRmZzwBOUnKrO7VJi42GEeF5eP2PA7iljO5GVfUKI6GOO@DObPoNdBPW4AuTZpHSIcCS0D0RHhI9QsIJvgK3dxqG2GywLbOeXUFny3MhDq3nw6Nlt0e92sXqzZuYUSFtGwmmmvFdYKk2N0aogmRui8XkwtPFLFjVfP/@vf9/9ID9Mby/mPA/odpv9Ir66l5ZEe6O2pebtOb6TXkW31Nj3O0x6YHp//139S@Y2/EBykjNfpz8aKgbU6Tm9ky1zkW3pjlR6Ky8tU7//87W/UhnnZsSEW63zdUYxYyVBky@0y71K6qqGVsi1diMQKG2YBhmgY0t6cXqAYNVpeK/AxXVprVVx72vOV0UfRUzwrZg1ZVUhOMow@Ba2MpEAZFWQFpFGhaKmY7oZR2wDzRmiqXx/nVgPaAfyq1TnCKkPVjccBVIbmZVtEHZiRGmk/Lw8bhVepUL3jZcrolJTMEhJbOy1r156W/g8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/4fwdj)

I call it like this (nodejs):

```js
fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('dotcomma/interpreter.js')+'');
code = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8');
output = interpret(code, "");
process.stdout.write(output);
```

Program that prints 347 ([try it online](https://radvylf.github.io/dotcomma/?p=WyJbW1tcblsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXSAgLy8gMTZcblsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVsuXVxuWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dWy5dXG5bLl1bLl1bLl1cbi4sXSAgICAgICAvLyBwcmludCAzICAnMycgPT0gNDgrM1xuWy5dICAgICAgIC8vICsxXG4uLF0gICAgICAgLy8gcHJpbnQgNFxuWy5dWy5dWy5dXG4uLF0gICAgICAgLy8gcHJpbnQgNyIsIiIsMiwwXQ)):

```
[[[
[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.]  // 16
[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.]
.,]       // print 3  '3' == 48+3
[.]       // +1
.,]       // print 4
[.][.][.]
.,]       // print 7
```

This code is on line 12 in the polyglot. The rest of the polyglot is skipped with `[[].[[[` (was `[[[`).
`[].` makes dotcomma skip the next block, see [examples](https://github.com/Radvylf/dotcomma#examples).

Answer (score 5):

## 400. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                            2222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11         xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';       # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
























































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullasge>Ex Cr Uithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML42yalet d=/;~ 16mb|>^ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({3d49c1df-3e97-4480-9ff4-81497478bd8e}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAAHxTpEqlUt2q2/XqKtW9102yWCAJkiiBAAsgJbIkVXR7dnvdtmfW09N2tB/j2/asZ9vriRjvxM66vWPPRNj7ccIxn/wDyo@NDceG@x/0nnMSAEGJlOq27YiJXUgE8nny5MnMk@dkJg66hj/6yU8SeLGnrr0Y2u6UTU1/yvqedWJ6MruzYLcNyy9ouiBgqn1vOBubztSvCgmmMmYbznBmDE02sOyp6WWZb5qsa9ruKcRrjO3OnJlv9hvg0xlzzFP2wOlZfYDApu6x6VhvTQ/i8ozdNe3z8fmU9dzx2HD6Ppt4ljOl2AJjTw3wDGa9Y2Z0/aln9KaW60BUkbEXjm2Mu32DUfKJZ/JMJQageseUZzWmzNgj1/NNKMHtmb7vYmAFAg3Pch/uP/74Uno1xz42AKmJbc4vFa@q7DPL9PqXc2js06N79y6H6uxrkuuwe1dRUvNsfzZ1H0wvwy@w/aHpGEyTK7J2ObIIxJyadjlXzl2OKkF7mlOrt1IORNyzPGhdI2hF1jMcaC1syx1mjifTBZN4@xu2HbWtzwyfzfyZYVM6Zzbuml6Y0J8a3tRyhuzUmo7YdGT5UT5K7U@Mnin1TdsaW1Ozz2wLMrmDAAqAdvrs2Fycuh40eQDTdewFZDR71sDCLCEeABCv1HRkcjhjYwGN7EyhczCD@YCGbYbQ0kIC0t81u7Mhc2fTyWzKALe@5RtdG4B2F6xvDoyZPc2yLsQBkSn8dGQ6QWcGcDKAOHI5Vq9nhJq57PNGv89y0I8Bj2OTWUA1QqvKdB3CmesB1SBViFEAjPo1r6M5hzaDJhq4VVbI5SD@MApBbA3bdwNkVlHDSAfGKrUZwn3quUPPGAM1@ibR9NMHT5nfcz3wwQ/T8vF0HZieMWW7uyx5@PhukjWiZpG9rhA1UZ2dQRMkwkh2Ytgz6CHxlnChfbwot4BNltxKVlkSyKLlWD7P8jBsy0wrAJHUXAUcMP41XYVfkWlllldhBBWYrpWSWSxr4BlDyzY5pCFCKmHnhyQa3HN5pqtlnnLo2gOerEcFlpheZsUSKxVYCe4VVtGgRASfZ2qlAL8i/ABaBdBR4afnOaBl34e@iv3tgA2MsWUvAugEvscKKisBRMBZBchaGSDAU9fxp8OP0Fq94rCnI6D4yDgB8JJtHSNHMiOmhM2owEPZ2VGIKyLb5cX7IyweyAeEK5RZCYovAiXygAJQVytD8YUcr4g/Mm07yDbyMRthW8rBDzAvAR3K0AI5oGUOiVmCH/iB52nA3DTgZBowJw0YiqaBW8ciIF0R4orQnMWAXiPDP4aCeDlan4gPXB3AqEhtZGQqEgkgQGsxHdqsyPLQGXTsDAWdAf6AS6nIgJeVVVbOs3KJAT0rOQZtowJe2FNU4KEq4KMiMGh/FTqACjipQG0VgKp6gQkxYqs6xkNeHfICadQ85MmDGxpOLeIP8kHPUKFIFcrUtMqyIwJuWgHqW9Cph2pFaN0SxAHdNMBVg@6kAbZaGeIxbxloWMYODN2WE8JAOkCrYJeHfgjEKAA@BBfSglsr6Zx@hj0ZGV3k2Dxnd4BZizgUikhGyJrD6sEzj9QEVHIABkcBoK9BD9BpxMAzHxVvqwCkieDNvkVM2raAf6kRhUpZ6pCvjcl0STa1SBhNFtNRFKbxMBeYpwUM0BwavUUUCaMvG0UuQ4s6hmrEb5eAcnkM9YG7ujPfXgKJHHmNijJPLHsZVqawvmn0B5Y/erfENU@FdE1j6ljHy1IKhWyMqEYsoogRK0ElPZ52akkwZQ1H6FrWRSthmokbNdAKyqpK6HXNwcwZmlKlHMOPYqYzbwqTy7LMCg/2rOEQ5uUlHDVL1aTJchlcIAxtXZ8KUSBSF8v0LJjCb7HeCISKKLLC4VcqSxi6hjAWRhdndgkkMZgJKjh3Daw5697q0cyxRFAnOvVG1iRMXN2YONa4VMi8XIz1DaLc23IuYs14teXXruWkkiyZFi4EmG@4dBmfrWFS@wxnKpx7sevC3OqS5LBknyknnB3TQLTViR5mXhvYKDRKz8BZGOckk@bUEI41lRkUAqKg6Z6g6EoT40oxPk2eXQ8lVZB0@qbnMUwL4q2fpWnWn3V9880MZaklXgOYt02Y3geGZUcI0DxiTEkIgGfSh/IWq2gPPHdMk80Yp1HbdScbRBaYtE8R0H331FyivpzTjcnEBskJwk0uuAEypwbJ3CSgx0vlCEEmzAcNDgCpKJA4LM/sEe2DqkNuHWSTVRSrTGvc0hHKnZhIpcNgAXHDxzzOzLarIOuYPaY3lL55omAIF7tWxS3EIRTEQJwKQHQNkJcRc8IignRLk0nEOwpb1nfHq1Xj8@uDqOojC4Uj@9RYQOsNYGo158YYpHqGojOMXDaGHsNbEFsC9Bas1gPWd53kNIJy6oEgC5WOakLCMtJkao1N0IBcyIItniekcXYnzLoL6MpErbxMKg/H5BKhZOEyoXhAPhbABwuIfP1ZD6mGZVsO9SAQk3yU8z1glTxMmHqs1TLg54FMNwm0PBkdmPA5ohZTEnw@2gPpu0cQUU41HR9UC19mFupg0POH7gA626kFdQeGBVmXsHtEBCRBFDSXe7JAJMcOND62mcV6kwmDcJiUoHvey5VBDHVfW@wtRNojUCN6M89bsPkEWsIaQ6ppzx0MoPe@NScjAMHGfdZb9GB4QiNj7xH6LjGY3mS1mkvftglpHFRMDp7@LBuaQHYQWgeooWKXX1ZgMqEqECkMhwu0jgGUwir0Jgsii5BY5hi4rozhfdf0qbO43nE09LEw3xzS0IBxNlgyozEK6NBLHVIs@sB5guGF8LFAYW1lsKigF3xsOjB0etArYdBD82Gb7rMBKNoxERZ1DaPXMyfToJ@4xM4sJybzP7mHMj@FSgEw2R8J27fZ7qVeA0mjnhOTZVEHQtQngSpiIK8NtHmJBI9I7eScxV5cKR5SnFwqXXyFaVYweCVuwGFCQwIVIGISsymyEuSOVm@EvHCK3IbkbRht3uxq9SEsXrw3ZtIgKhuxUYHtCLISBSEem2FI8LOvApInNsJqrARg0pWAG0Ab/ngNZDdC0u7HQ2XFkIEp3gR07DruGqhAzAguJlmNobagzvgcuYZhR52Rhou/0kbIsJcLTDiRwRw6mbgejAzOdBa0mkBNFutdgRKeiuaKtMzurE6tMGUkccKf4iwIGSa2AX0BhxiOVNCsDOAUwMS4kgw8z@UlxhCmUU@wAvxOifXzzgRzqeOYqJwZ3oIDgerB9AwFLZjlecAGT3CS4HNQOJnI1E9hTjD6feSsSA4a95cLl7FHH8y61vyyJt7DQPm1L5wYHhugEu6B0AGDKJUc@Ml0jcIpZyxKVNzJVKGs/C5CQkokQ5OnBqDXwyRxDxjN84XTS4krQ0zMMnE2HZTFNDgwI5fR2CegKlzGDtUH7DTjYxjX5KuxIUzfkgR3CcMIE4xQZIwwPJAzYBCCllmp9LsGOwfu4TFpfsBVkVAlUeV8VJbp9KOyAkIgLvH6yrwI3@uRQ4rNalgDTE41p0lihYAfSAnKKEKAogRzKwaQtMfjSK7hgTOH1uJYiosiaXYWCb8wAaQIGQuED6tnTTuBuHLrVii4bNXr0NlAmgK22U/HNdpw0VIGTg2JZZJGgkLkqft8imMjlYb6YuILjg2ITdBT6w12Nh15MOLIfyFAIiCr4GBPDgkbtPNj63jWv9zQDgZiIhFHHQhNVm8q1gSY/PloqF9H1eQKVUHrTSJVsfNifgJ9pfNSKDaoGCTzTB/F33qASqyFU4hB0FfXkohnDcKWHfpg0bMDkYC7YLBzbtQF9I@DxayIEWUDmSActFdGKgeCw4HDYU/3j@7Xg7HII5Wu5VRXAmy3Z9gUvI3JxTDvwwd3nu0/@9nOGhi21a1eDlCsfLmIU@1sLg2dmZKXtep2HMYS8N3O9bAx42oaUQiimeTOY6LSogeTyzwk55NnX7tMEpCEkBxUArjxd0mk4WlA6BK6hj@6NAmzYSYDRUZZwrRMesBCmJEDUcd4I8Tn6eztW2y8y0hNgnDEzJ4ZHEAYqDxwwnwyRl4SwMKo7oDPiJQXpFDLwc2GpSueMsTnY5SaLyNDonSsy3z85N7hszqBDdbVJEqi@FOQpQyvL0Oft2eggq9LA@wPXD2WkZeIozxNuK4lcK@3QuBl27IN8AEA6jqyyyR7HFbNHwHuB5frRqFSL@oB5CcIl@XKuDzU@7KIxvDAKa6HKu@6WZQilpNVFLR2xopiV6etXqFglvKV@LTVW5bZjwOljQGYB0K50YOoY1/CEHkpRQZidYD@84dXEPdJiARVQAox820mU1m@LaD2Ilks6SsHoKG5til/RhxPZGJaUZLh3oDc80n5jKU/nFvTVC7Nn2oa0kLp@/sPtLth4mDJmlYySGlAXRxnJm@Ae3w9H/qI49ru0GU7kIdLh2GBIDZtrOb@0HWutJCBgVjVBG4TAv/FhRtjAnON9ZYUR8oVV1f5hqPh@KfApdWijkQiChEohdLLr40TA8i1rPfzB984hElELeRykTtHF5AglofIha5eLJQCmAQFyQE@aysYbRleGe1hhBTbs8NKB4wuyri/jF4bSBxTVtamX4vSJ@4Vir92F5e6FoTwrgWOGMkePH768MHjw0f7n7emWqGw4s/nKkUgHJTXBVlIHnG64Wjd4UMTq4XgEjA2PBxewAVmoKCEO0Yz3wPGLWMSmSOwodfwzdbUJ@7ISfrpy5U5xVjptdPjXegRDj6eNMgIinbfRmXE4zvWOJ9j/xlNpxO/qigwykezrgxKq/K659rGUKF8MDHYtqKi6vLgCa5r@OtyADL@wuQ5@OIWiA4LWkE07LELygvteyNrYCkOnlatbGs4Al0YN8dNLy1HPZhqo/RBQwBdWYnqRgyYfEDb4Bm2k8i79ldVrcz7tZrT8ooYJlsZ/pB2a2CC6pSC2QpIkb7kZa1brVtsAVwaIV0GkmDyDi1y@AznApuBIEmrpqjnh8QhboHrpcgriEZvZriaC1xKKeTyJbVYUEAtAzUNZFYJ19yksTHtjaSpKwE8yR3QukGsFw78nuEM5J3AESILct9HUFW9@bLVctogoLduEW6499xctJtqO11jV7PsBOnTNei9K9XDvhsGQN8lJ3RNerIN/KxvXGVnfYNGV58p0/EkmHOkCXu0D4LUWxf4dd@Mjz3MoMQjlZ2VtAomfqesWRCyMauAN6SUAgMKZlroegriJYHQi@Ih9BzgW7EMbLmaEQlMi@kI@IfOUgfkSl@VcDFYD7jGKiq4KCxPFsDyKBEybUlHhMIIKnDCISAqSVCBUOLB@CRHgR8zibEy1Ptx6Flu0qdtGhStcMHWn0A70np3DycKH5copzBBR4MPJwroXzhPsFMziUv5hs8XTCFTcNQgzA/qYgSBNgaiRXEnOlwB/ZBy0QoBMC/o2rhyO1oudOK6A3R2KJBwwvUPEGIc2sAYQiUhM6/IPq8IL4lCVqt07LinDkLrmqwsda0p329wZx5uuVv9eN0gua7xNACNKhebWmhvvmv2@EIvz0y1AD3UYGNz7OJqBgh4xI1MqoLB9/VRHfVx0RxGdk7CTUuAL7HbB8BIeyZfspLGqMdBrz5kyamn7EvfUAzpLQyoa8Q7rHysiYNGPwoJsHrKghZqgkVYEpDcMSX6jJZ8MPJOKHEHXQt7lmjU3YnpXFY7uVKaStfoNEQyyfehzpJbW1vJarKRzIJrD1y76NpDVwZce@SSyIXpZHRRjiy5MLZJOTCsnbxohpDn6Tb2gTkKL2@tScpoVqt6O2s01eCp4TMNTQGUh9QSPgBOMl2vozOdFhunuG0EKkSs7gfYd573PGsSkOATkEm4Pz68xGB4eWYN1ePrKTKue6C3mijlprxkq5lrtVtnrX6mdZHMYu50zaiDigr8c5oay0PPnU1AdmzmqxKw13RTr7Zr3Xoyl9xJpcqSDQUZ6fRH5XTG4LROJU3oU6lWKwkkDajT7I08gjfPaul0RCjAY2CBomPbqaR8Vobyu@l2OpOEvOlkFmaGejIJdKE9T58qjYsSvBPds@ZAShiYMMvGtzWIR9P@GA7Xb5iT0cKLJ4gW/kDQx0X85ZEZPFmEE0mcUb/l@eMy5cpiQyh683QgX@P6IYpskwWfYASOaUtZOaAVTv0n0mDsTg3lUxn0Njk2Yye3kookwWRMMRwSVfuR5eMQNhzTnfnxxc61a7BYOoQejWbALMNTclnoVdZEMHsjlyW3bwN0Fm05IePH3TOJ78GFAPo9GX7IRFEwwv0aEHDoXJMFfJFOhNHCkEpIcNYTbg8UipM3clRajfKwHBZkDR3XMyUgCeQQ6BAXHQ0UGuHW@ANafLsy/QSxNKviVGaZwBHv2a5BtOXsOrYlNRnH8jtDzPLM7As28I8BsEeZt4Vn9pUdgTaKXW8EMwTUBjmxFrXWOIhQXH/Sl6dzyCqkcM6PR3IFE@TeU9bXNK3YKwyqYRz2CiD2CBoJFWMHtOwwSlIhMh008iFfmQqXCR4/uXvIl29ovscZHpfyOmO3PwPRNlDdnpnOMMsOoT9Zjju2gAxh/rfH9jPXnfKFBvBsWhziers1ntkGLTtdXhm6Nl/P7bo2rUZdl3WZfub5hm3wdbAwdv/TR6BuvDh6XpersUSKcTK@tmxcCl1fLKfng/i2J235hjtUPu@Y4nZBxHkrPHyKbCaIKGLELDh6Cm0UhpcwPBxSuI0ThJcxfIzHTkFcDxYyyBsFBgkrlBCPouK5uyDwTM1dYPhGNTBKp1I6LrsusT1TNQo/mQ4GK8E6BR9LyJrsZXCegvmR1BU1NY5SgSfC86kraeKAipQmOqa6MV2J0vEDNnK0ufkoOgcxMu1wd/MZSCy4gweTvo1yFehNqCXwo6QmCPkT3Kgh1o3bf6wHcrB/RYqFwTaReGohsUUDCCY3BUUaYVthwfJ7jYaQ4wbbpj5nq66X5Ss7uw2@0Y5qncc1SoVvDGx3AMRuoxae@duUDEtKJqNkBJVwgxxUTTpbcKWq0UkRn9b7BcpSE3wFNJq5lpNa89Jh@zyp@ESGARNbrflHOe1zUI3w0Ob2LWVo1uiY1QZ61cKYZCDDdhdMAokPU/G1894I@AzLzFdJCe0zcwau3Zf4Rh10GMZVPGyg4JxEdJg0ODNsWl54jpQO8vKsyF9jR1CvwL3UpI2rCWKHViNAMHzO2Plx9uScNWHKO5H9iW1N2@xCnrqdUXBYy7l8vJXLoJ5nLHwhOGZTZ/vPPv60mWtzCMLYwM23Mm/FeXhKGgRnEJTwODu48LDQ1JqSJECHISysryoDUnPapwH0AQYvoMaigoIaIern5vmyLgMTlOWUiZj7i3GWmekLeWAb06np8D7Hd0A3k5tvVQXF1Kn4vWDfo8pytDkEkqmFcYBijT0/unv47JkMPddPJQ9xE6kKw9HojUBA2VTpkJLxylfZR/0k@wjzpHHlQIChBtpHJ8gPnboGnR70DygdecfQ9FIQmMb9nx4E05YbZeQSWkAgPPLVmxKNImApMw11ImDVtfi/cLiqFeBZhR6fIUoCuVO3qkBbKy3PHOuN7MNEQ3IrJAmUVZgv6tsp4mLbajo40zfG3WvQsEhohBo0m0x6C1wOEous3a7xYwiQFhUwb4jUFUVqCjpMX1fDpq9DMIg0BCHIXn/HXjZzUqWd2V4His63Befgef1jcBHCKmjfXFvsdorG@5WBzHHg25Gcc78gdfrSSyBVts0dIl/2puThmS1iOnTEa/Wo1upBMBhkyEpoNQgrErKERPCWQtBnKZ44P@g8mI0CUml2FhFdQ5Kz83OiIdvWGNEQXCrjjXERap/AmB66UJuHwRsKcemARmtwlgXHbEsQQzVrdbMYY7gIr5xckk6lEzGej0uHlnPs0pZT5OrkZLWAEmGUe3xsX82J52DptpI0woGn1TZh54@7A7qtSUA7L8GePgXQmn4gC4MQaSjP6EHL@2tKXj3HslJscEKWZlpwM@nNDSmlSpkSD7pda1NSIAIeTQufa5IBk8L@rMl5WQ1fecClGJiPgHFx7WVZ9ctHoNgK3YOjvMHzv3yzD/S/2jojmChw8TNydGDqxpaSBhsbK8iKHrqtb1i@Rj@zLYMIQ66bQPYMD6pk2JFjPWg6ByBJMP2PcVcjaHHom3gDqfGabsYx55uS4XN9Iev29Rxgmb1NaS8dCeNF0Q4UKHZ9IgIXgiyTMhHr4o1gzvkuUEzFRjZ2M1LhuS1GnZm3@2g2nfE7CK43NqI1wd91YzNImSsYXdVU@OH5a5rcM45nfVeaHA8jObW4Ju2y9rQNLYE4EOxId9C5vvq8gvwwevjclGw5tSmn9LipV/jOzJ9IXdLC@9xHA2F8TQmeze@bkljBO4SRYzPVLJtuH9gTA@jQUYIDGQoed5ViRLMukdk2uguUQUZfvpdFhxuA49R7mUxO37C7PZlszo@aJOWvVNbnnss9To91awQKP1Ir8VU0qnBwyPaGVoXpyhobtqT1Y86NzHzd2YgrSaNtVcqD73/QSyDXdnKckHoz2/CWrmu6@BKPcBth04p0MG08tXouiAMTppZkVQunjtiEQSwzPJ23LAhPNNMtdgLDWkfG8I0WKXKtZwFub4qnVjf0qQ9gaPy0KJ7JjXUS2d1EqZ57ir@N4sMIVFN@Xz@jvV2L1QcwJ8nu2QbM4xung5XFQVx8vKGjnlq@Sbf1hD1ei@i0Z68NXx0C4bJffBnvpm7tW7brs@d0v45AQw@owO/rO3SclpbhSLQYHndfw4PCYxbLBjXsoWsXy0PFgNvGVp95A@T7wfNDOVzEoVT1Bg4Vij@uowbPjXz9WPGOb2ogemfSwyO2Mec1U@w6NhXsvWyuHSgGuHG3vmb3cmXKKSt8qW9DwbjlcmoswudPMXVsIm04dUwWJE6DdIcZKmVwTD0uYv80peWvL63/YUzpCtjSTZWINe6xbcJkRfcrTcq0nPolc6i53IezqIE9M2fmWkXjSfe1iW/3X6NkfDhSuaAa28FKPW4O4NsxUaq3gWb4QVjjPI2@a5mJYVs982ZRZpWpTUD6nqDq/BQcT9FxNcfQmU1WWnVFO3OeXU@y0SQc0m5/BTuM@bJ8qHyDpLQin/sm/a7VmLiGh2fU6oVcLhcIMLEdlxXPdZqUHuV9bfH7SsEUsix5mRZ32byYc30ZRJb4KciNLEjbpNhT4kpFcSzHnC7w/oHctOu69pdpKWCq@M6yC9qqRKd9r2uxK@JO8B4LWy5d@Ljg0R1sWrTgs02gWwJ9UGm@rtHjW0If1JoSbnqOcUNq1Xv98k1sg@mmUvD9WlwT4ud/7c2yZLAaospluXTtqOMSqts1bYM/5sX8dfAqsn4tvFWmEWzW4uYu39JdbsUnLjGlyQKIZfVBSxmZY5O810j5Rh8tdQSPjYnmLv42Rc9Ns6fMD83epgQTC/iCg/eVPeSYsDR1HdCvpnjUEPUUGw@zBqGbOHC467eWyA/GxtDkpmOu45TLBQs8TcPVuqVz/dJFlZ@g6UG2pU2QzV0CBtWxufDD51qAjxY9aNfZ@ObltkuDv4droB8w2jedor06xTojd@SMzBE/uh75Ng0O6I9TburnOtQB6@EIT9NNJiun7OP0tF3b/hB6ImvkjNJ1B2txOsT3b/HlsS8Fl7/sHzxuXLwzppx3oGPjqBmZM5iXfHfqTkyJfJuS2rjQw@@beGi4Sf3TriBdq@cDRcLnTwv/Rt1yaLjTyYQenYk98@lGWSV6bfomuWnAj6bQuUzXG8pv3XFXDgLl4NwKbYGvZzFda9ob4XvrvGebQ7fbG1k3IR3YylDCJR/u/SDdFSljMekuBsu2BeT1FjL2l3o8/jk@Hmxq9GD1iE9rkeMaeWXdCh29GS5NjOOez1dD0cWquCAcG438/fEqvYFffTOzpkugsbNM0fIu35ZAxybcg9MTGyUrek1jyYaDUxUbeykJ6SiQS2YOBB51U7Gr59xiQ0zX@W0TQvFaEkaxcylfhtzB2R9aHbRi67YQvtK/Vg4trZ3knNFs6F9lmHy5vg8iGt42L1vQcerYkjXMWYYTPDaRWbMVfM8Snh2QuWbmtXsqhWs3VSidakuGa8GjAw9outnGNTTbmvj8zqTBxq244CwT6OKX9ws5bRbrlemgYfrmgG@BoOsmEXHsengSGWQQqYc76biCjsycC16ccTnuEJi6ZLNl4jDtJrFl7TGh9c0fzZnS54/NoYFnrR9aUzysuaZXUJddd7zoRthfnxm@9fUZ1GxTZ0OjEXwb0otbF0DfGniPjKHVu7/SEBGSAYGDk578sdL9MehqW5yOLB9PNEWOaxamsMvxToy9rgN6w5qUl9ftI3sZywHE38Rcm3rd2ro7WeALawtyXbesbk1plTV4blIdNx0CuxaJ09l4MvODx3oc6MxUfBV6fEzh/qkFwKU3wFrZyLCn61eqY0uuIIUFk@LSuUka/4Zlu0P2jXKOgdAGQhgK52s6zh2Ynp/igRzPWdMTqewP3PbEhQ7J4xV7A21r4nsVjjW9fjVnOsXDOeETK8NnDnxDQXmId/n2l4UgHa2nyMObZf3l29E3zO/Q8567M69nojMyeRJXC4JSzYPw9DG@0eGiyZbTuJbWc20YXuCw1w6ZnuvMppI3c66dFYrXzgpVNHgV6wYs9fXDRy/S8d5Ap7VvkkJDk2hL18YDA5c6meWAILaZj66mDnWJu9xU0zM6KnxDnn20J9Ujdn3XXafvPF3ABPLBChMw/9n4rtnDbcMby37sPnIdF2ajCTDK8TOTmx1YOeixPiNme4gv1gN9@jcW85zAbpiEuLRhTMwutK@9dH3IXMQB3zWmxoapiNYGSf@LXDf2Fcvumt5rWvSLuTeptKsI3TfnpFts7jB8DErTXo@LxLgetzJGVnZs/InrOvxO3DYHD/XR9VwFpgK6ffhGuYwH8VfWBdbqZ6tVfXLCT4mYfW4XY1NdPbPr2vx@zZkkx@JnAgzPMn3lIZpZoLBinkkgffnX8pDStTxkqRqBJHti@LRJv17VWIJU51/iCNDI8Hou7oQFjmtO58RsI9zApqOz/fzgQBcIPweOZfRmgb3Sm9Cyx90x3TYqDLHWfGZ28a2gLhkUmRrzq43JV4YCawqxE12RDYKQXeGgLrLUU9BG0jdPWyt61CpVrQndiFNv3C6nwzqSY5m9twaumrlEr@Xa9Eo81Fl5TM4Na9WxYUSryIpBL9uvHUmrR9dAoLFNaTryQOdXptctb4eWXtbsh8zGJm4yr@7CbBRdXX9ElXXX76dHzNUzpcDcIPCSyPQglw@l/Y2SJ4KH/yd3PlFgEu4U86H1E2BdN@/gA/IzzwkeH9IDn7r@dGDNnwDe@BbAJnaC1SpAFnjwkYGunU2VgNZzZjZffRjGzl2N@6SOSWQMWpJsYtdTUzKdE4ls0c2v1sjlL30p@2hAeGr2pcAUA@40SA/D97@iZMFzzQZqnDfiYU9V4YSdF/PB8c91xD0NOQPIW@5Umvj0VCb@0wcPnxzJE19dOz/tj/DtiCty3IptB62ciy1JvTa82H4nP47Wt/ypcue5Kh08fCBjgg305jsaEjxwZ27lsXHdMzQkqxgbtSCMNafrBcT7R48eZpavaLLUwchzx2Y6Hn3w/HkW3zT55Pna6HjuezA6Bu58Y/YHh6qaXtN9Xzi0O7iJe64paROkIxO0UeiM97lpmBuFq547MftHi4n5KUyeyMH9Dyy@uLGSj40Ta4ijkFU2EooGKqvIxXw6djIblG3Ti56b2vPYmiC37NFD4Y@Nx1FQctAVT18vPVy3439ZimG54CTCl8uk5q721rgpY8Xw/76Iqaq6ic7PjQG0KytsbKzVBOv2h2335AO2ks1AeZGiIGkKvUqybjxHXpLGwLoVvOHyfBAIzu7GYzDXAYiCi2sH/KnpLAxHor2s68SLKuTGQ23XJvmG@QEbUtEJnxO0l752jy86Us9SPXKmbyj4yItlOTi48@CmDM8CWl6f6uPHL9hTw0c7KNcnjGNsfgDGS8notYTrVmiEb@N2at8DUNq18IaT9eO5yp4bXt91FvObN@HoHVSc2sm@cQQLfZTItK25tW6u6vF1rafrjxndVDZ/icNdrMjBcfs4AaD33/4XqprLkfUjfKo57r2hZcIBzlLoMhZoUi8edfQgYg09lFtkCEiv1UYfmnM8jsJXg9cp9Wvnt@I1c18pvXk6uS6ufE1c/pryrsRhINPlnHoNwMI1cawgR9EPXft05MoHhmf6a84fr0XouopUrqlIJcadA4PttLEYuDeL@PjqQvBY21uPzKmXn4zcrpVfW4f9Adq5ZI/QXvvV@OA4heHR8ZahG7zywf3ryzudmWsLemS8XR9BnOZ4bRQwQXM0o1cirkavbpB2QeY1naHFTTyyO@70kHzXKGbRG8/rzyJYk7uzyWaMgTfiVzEus/OVhJ@Bzuye@uwOvhq3FNPX6P54Pm59@CaZlkULg2jp9P7Rfti7njxXtFiJSyw@f7oSjC@PTp88j4V55ny@SemV5pt0yLUxy1IfH@VXit1tvDxZQ6zN7xuBuAH8OHpulIM4s/vk@VWWgOrbaDq2w5hPDGe5YrrSYH13Sm8aro18upjTMcq1LT3ip9jWxXm9NcErij1MyJYFZftKp4PmmDqdTb3yyPyc9h5ADGJTLpZwoIHhJXOeH4UYUpaNA9U9Xgo/K@g@n4wsZ742arwpD50iTb321w@Dffbcdk/Zw8iq0Cb2oK0HbpyYzibmtO5lRamiXy@F6ZdEqk3twj@gEjw2NcmdTYLaJZ6BByKu4yaY/1lPuRd6PtXSN6b/5HmY/Oa0B7aL6/d9aza@OTGBzWRuTuhdw/4uA7RuTobfGzkeuZ5zc9KwO1Wrd8wPRGLrg1OOFz33A3DoDgY3Jzr03ZsTPZrZUwt1lvVJH7szGy0IrIs79IZrwxu7jVZLrsqbItGguz/y0pvj8VykO/NBB7Ii5hlllF5b05XAsM/Ew9C@vOnIjpu@BPcTl30NLcmvIcXbD2yjT@5tSre6YTPDLX56I3jp3HSod7LQbxzkb60heT5k0DnW@Nq0S5N/DzzX4b70pulxaf5vTUn3Ddu6kaGFBx60G44@4ITG49mJfjPXAgHh3uY2@3QxX6qbyxj@6j/MHPEvV/jZwPAXN5XBDRT4cvh5kVTKgQ6WXv2WW9zaAtp3T22jfeNtsqwAac/P2VZgzQAixNA@QmC/Ac2gWs7MRAMM/AtP0/o2FFOvq4UK28OPp1WZmqMy8ZuQFW5tMiysybbPAtsE1ap6wbbqTKyKLLAOERmP5wbQATCaboZKMelYZdtTiNkOLRsw@pYPO2e0ICv10EIu@GQlbuOlFth@AJy2z54@eHr4/Gj/6MXzZq59EdiGCGvhOFBaaIHmI70vQuUDuoGixz@HQDZJbCiOvjOEC7l@WC@G3y5brVp9pWrLSol7mGf7zHEUhcxjKNIF4CeJvDSKRXEFgjjssMbUQIFllCq3VEEGN6CNOGiRyoRGq7LcuoInBigt204Qf/lTfxSLn4Os4gchseDAgj30xKHr9oMSfZPdfIUl3tt/8PDFs0MWIrjsNadWfzqqVwr8AwfcZA@008Ci88J1lgyyJKGt6vXkvSQQJiknWZUMmtDHBaCjQ7KQOmgKJci9w1LbBB8omIwaRfkv31QukjK@@pKGtMkQqSQUC32eOsrW1hY7gk7C7j578OnhM4b4H96lYCQRgmBHaE3hz37Y55/nCa2dhZ/C9MakYZC1KCFuUSU0M7K0hII0p7E72fxBTPocDtkbib7DE31ITBDoM03Qb0/JVuolI5ZpsivHP@AZ2BgNC6IuFH7SA3dZ0V4o8i7Lt9DaCeIwQPOdq50dD2aS1VyZ7ePXPvGbogZ9KwpQnzlTbiIvMJSVgJ4mRzwny7YJWf5lKTGWMLm7BZ29a4LyyXzHgulvWmWvoSfiTmaVW8ORpEbySpYQdJVcEiossYRX7H36SstT3v/yP1OGNQbuKbi/E7jnuTvg@8XANwD3L3H3SwU72lX7oEtc4gihWeGgBhyRiP5I@9hHTh1ugWhJODRjGjJWZo2hmU6I6picl8DvEvDjJZxU81NoNOhu0GKB5SFenum1U2jXuKoo2KVwQUSmWdyc80PYl@wbFwvFvKoAktJJCJA@SDJE6xIcYDpdhWEinFiT@itQsnd3d5mIq6JmvVjjLatsOy918VWE6DakFWDWBOSaDPJAlmUOiGsE2WD2yahpzIrcK6kmkXH1XZiWKB6nL/Q7ASFElgJicRqZ@IWLOX4Pdwq6QmCnu4tfkI19rGo7ACSpMCeRKy0Kgc2ex@4Uug8M0uXn6LjNHnwJgU@BaH3W51@JJvPY2B/lqyNraWoi/CpWMNZk5AEclJ67PJvG21b8DEE8RxBVcV33bb5krWnLaSu8bzLopj9Y05kdcP@CMtzQZ3m9969aJk5dtiuMxGK3nzsuLv/eg8qwlKZouqIW08sq5fNrqxTUKCgGqoPmz86hOGBTwDJ6pvXanfj7B4cPPnny9PkV67uUMnk5GfD9xm6mJcnZZjtyJOPVWm2SO/eU54/u3AsbYol0McaNgfEHNVGvq8lyVwdBLt8SvFy1dRhert1mjD/jdkQu46tr16FGma7goea@RLn0po50j963vVy4Vl5HrULhOpSW8JQY6ANuLOEKqqn02UWzDbqXk0he7QlrBsLLhLyDgwBcLX9nW8HOfrVyWLHo@@1H@FVMPz4W9fVjUdzW0bgj2mqZusdL85dBQCwiVt@wGGCRgqyESTeOvidcSF8aadX49@W5Vci4zbsYwsXcdRSPgToKP1WPXGRpYjqwrjwCvci2ukJoa5BbWQ6NwUYGlrmdwFRaCL6VxAtOBR@vn1fnMh3LTaWR2xGsLLvOYHMILy3AgEbp7ukM9LOn7oR/O4OOX901Q9czF9jv3RlfrjXZJ7MxpBvQ45lJW@HAuSXIDJRMRqhyWQq4RGCveZ5Bi9hQXhOtNgcVl8f9QmqelkfmvG8Ngben0lngaB@paptFNp2x0mTD2UmK1GbLVrh2KH6MJjDiZP9Shr3nSwSMpiFbTt@cp5KnyXS1DeVjePL0s5NkWlzXl8jAeGBxu3/Z0niEfkm9npMY02B0hma813GLSuUql4Cwy4C5xcvww32VijzyBfoQax0l9@dT7yE4QYxIDcbGhKVmDrcWKjPyplopJ0tmFKUGt0TssEyGFCp4UITMKOeAXHz@ThnOgqWUOn6rF0J9p4@Pt9aENVVZboObCkmzbfyg5gFIXGg/Ny2AEgxZqgS2jl0I1AzAiA8SmXdwyIPxkBYeZHN1TTR9X5B2DF2kCdWaNW6x2AdSVyVHsVKpBg26yhUrDHrfVXYoKwD2Cp8L5XqgbmBIDGgG6q8sJJaM/CrHS1C5CY7I/cACGaCTiFkPDw2TMYC1tO3dG3n4Sx06MFZAPqhWXxzd65TTisgiS2ZDz@rjjjb/Bkek4gVfTYNhqqwkTda4RvcxZkObsR1uKg1Nl96jASNeYqmJOBkCu9uhsuwv@6aqXtvrg4xBK0DKPE4AwRvfnRAc2vkNV4bWxK1n9j/5SQKFjdS2qh53vJNMspCrwU2tFViBfbTdkqTtZq5@e9sALWr6Zt4CnVzZyZ@Yd0eD/oOh0hJFprO8ouycnZ0l7@08tV4WWFHqW1rxzXxxoRf1N/MLXS2/OZ6oxab8Zt4Wy/XscZs9ffr5u867tDg/WbwRWyktcfDkXFTzqPInqhV2tlfUE8cVUD@hXMaO2Vu4jgcM/8n9th9zG@juDkCFTYos0WoBxVWxJCpKM9mGf1L3X8HFFf9mQ27Ie@1379JNw5jOF8yyrInf78PPHYEEqaWfM9CXbwGn5xkU1qInaVB4jeeDq@sJBcbm@@ZwODs0GhoaA5Bvd2oLa3Zv@ugbn4XXC7zePotlext8wTuTSUlSc806RbVjFBL4LfA/@9HWRfbsaWf3z741VswtfDzBx3cuHqH7uVr4aGvrozt38vmspmnc/fQbT392f38/fzdbeNos7OWl3Nbun/7J1pam7WrKVtv31XayeXz8uajl8qL8Z7@T7Dx9@nXfb@j/5zffNVS8leB2wkrAJ@DSmQpOvJfhp6KM9aFX4m0CermaWNBfJxGGn20xtbFX@q/fe/ImMU00NOUzD57TxJtEsZzgTnCATw99J4lGYheTFS8SC6Ver4Oz9F//HeRvfAJwMGaxC7dGIYRVXCQaUp2ynCcaRXComgbl/t/f/GYMQ84m6iTGhddt1oRLzJc0ca8N1w5duwJaiJVyihKmc6ajqekytXxLvYUeCzzwcEz81IY5bSXUcp49uQ0pnzUzmUxb7khwyS9pkUhRVa2lqreAHUgf7dTr0g7jNnB1vXAL7finaUlr6MKMad76bOVKfPYPcq0FU/upwT0TEsWt26/uNhpQJ72h7zQydAUDicZUqSy67m2RZdmrJKggzfYrVnuIUQ0xV9bEbDZ7u0NJ53OklTSfhz0JL35PJKIQHLLsUlgDR3ubReE8F7ual8VBr02XOMTrz/@3P//@n3@P/r5Pv/@IJnSdvjVQdiDRCQyJBly3q9VeoyE2PPGshf4G9KNctVwtK52LVmqn2Wg/Y2ru4/NkQU8@Z8j9VSyjlW41KX@Dim0ExaO/kVgGN3hIIx4WRPDEFADPgFIssUo1ckdUY@xSOphag5cNpOZJoy2hQFSXmmqx0JZ4ruZtaBxRK1XETjshbS@A22jthlbQnrDbDX6x0bbPXMRG14phRQJ8G8u6LWOWvkY8KNEIszWWab5sugCnipBoNpW2SfNBI0T09lZ1q1wtVjWl09h81ZY58KKkpmk@9RMnieiqsaAfhvRMRD0zFvYy3hJRs7CwA7OVvDekg7a6fq0bm4ZRc@lFVawFLq0jshr0D02XtGFHzKliNNioF@zBtQV/9A9X5MX7FoUEwZTk6rXFquqOpiuFj4qHGs6vN1xxlAWYJ1iv2@2@7XVB6jCMrtEz1KkxM@bGwph2Z915d9qb9RgfNAGLwH9Pdwtu2Z0HXllK6AV1O3EL66RrFa2Mn1/Uy2W9ouklVS8V9VJOKxf0ckUv5fVSCQDqJU2vVPKaphdLerGsF4t6sQLhGqQpQhodIZQKekUXEu@aW@wZ52ttlgmvVubG64UsdwInOVz8SZI7TwiJf4SroWoq24EZLwc3EPPICVo4/qmqwBIgup213@003@3AkG9kdondthtSgCU85M7tdka6uGiCu1YL/ncbkbNGF3dB5doXmczuywbIMy8bzQyAfBmAlCVGQOVOo71LMVFhQWlB9G4bJCIps9vcrbsH9JNpzEnJvJssurfbAHh3BdnbtzMyuG4DgMY2DPF0JrMtSVs42zaD2QcStxuZsFaIQwrkj7Ozn/IHqiPwj4vdi8ZFc/fiYncX/nfpfhE8IfRi98o/PZbXhjTL@DbynlZTabSUVsB/2uCXlQaGyEoLHA14QrqmrpXbOOOh1CK3/9v8l7PLexSCKLdlwFpI7LCdBJqI1RM7QuLV@y/@F/y13n/x@yiBMvgzq0LiDBmFsoP6a4WrsXBjziOHPeKXA278hV4MwYDGIwx0@M3BLS5FeSWzKt9FSKnlYlrGKb3jDjpodUZmryDpClNFLspErVwUOxl1obHErlgsEQv9mStXMpn8J6@0SinJl37QbMor3/cfxbBc4gmJa1pOldTzBv8yCP@I08@su/7Jz2y6hMR5hZlVoE@KccIICehHCUWRpIaQaOyO8b0a3HyRUM89qX8uvdiXcGHGmNLWWo8vOtQfHNYrlQZqPeb2Uxo0O3d34K7C/@EW1IK1BpC0Naj3xiBRtwZ6QWvhVyQSUvcN/j18i3/sqId/z97gHzt6i3/PpvjHHnXx7@gN/u138e9ojH933uDfo7f492KIf62v6LpaE7fPiDAZtaJebM9FIlAtwfYara9MvUWVPokmansa6JHB0lVKz1fSidZXzHnPnEyrwRojvuRk9qY1o16pdetakDQ4oY0xsuWH35wPlhSrGkvj4qdeKbiehMcJ4QYBGb2iul7yx9/91reS9XpSStLXrPIQJnUxUZcSgRdy5jkm@JVgwA@a2/eTtdvJrzRpWaFQaTcxsg0RQqLOttVtNWfnejm1q3bBYbGcx3Kj3Ejtq6R@5UyWW@QWLDd21T64TPjLgcvKDVhuyHJOzoFkEAuuaSc3RdcAHkP4GwAgD/4sPKneVXM9BgXZKIrSh3vVDubMnXdaQpMlmfjKBP1ZVuWcXLTa@K2xpvjqVUvZaWuVMpOxW8ud5qtWsi22RPz@hFbJs@7C3Gq9EkHgyIm8@2MIS/g@KOW1hNJqKZzwQC5qyYuLTufw8d1OR8GJsPXIfbL8f/JkHPde@z9@4j564o5d@H/y5AkMXrORuZ2BKeL27TpMGcFjL9Go7bWqNPGEk09C2d1rNXQJ3cUMzCcahmW@5LWECM/GVktInoJSdAr6VC0FWtVp7aRWOyXHZ9wLjg66MTD6Pw0cwZMg1CKd7BSuEwJLPnSeftaKXNyhfHYKQZ8x0CWjf1Ba495/gH/rv63/Ry9YmqWa7XTq7GI3RVca/9Lps4uzi@DeSKdSgSe1C38YAH7McnbRQCclOgNXM5Vupy8ueBjcU@ldDrABxew2KO8yHUxMiahIKpbfUv@wTyg6uFrJGgNGSOsFhRyNo4RYY8byrFCrNc/l0sDngk/r4M63cU4HMtI1@q7qdreptv/0d@jzSXtpSlTI12rqDuMeLa/VavnQVyrXauXQs51KVa5ejdyeWgSlKp9Pp2s18OyFYHPghbxN9i7D6qwF9/atW7yQsnZ@HsLU88VMDs9o1WphSQUo1vSNXsD0zx48oS8PAaspJPCTX5yVpHL03TKcCJJiVbx1K9U38XWI/t5@@tYtrZI7P49CJhMIUleCOp2@5XU6GK6fn4sdkc72VArgz5XPz9VcJaMm066XeowfVYWiUpLKPtIaVGoFmLyWL0F0gEBhd7eYbzSKeQgplpNpPCfAWTzgmxSTNTFxRnVQyyXOAcUaBkeqGAxkHyfas4sEtSbLF9Ip4KJpEEEvEvjnIcPlE12hkK7lc7nE2YXIE6uVCk@dZvliqpypBH/1rTRrgJjF/1BW1DP5ndLObZC68c@fr7uQJ9fOzLp6UT8zq7hTcFEDUcF3QUhC6z3mrVt6BUhUztVaQqdzd/9ov9Opw1yGohrcMJC4u4BGjbxktXab2lUtFxg0IA@UkjAlsDJQWdF2CmoZqSJYA7TGBWQQuMq3xbYEjZ54EyqcWlsQCBoUlNaHi/VZlw3xYkPUQJnFbLqYzXg83Xu9KJHLryA28lJeUlLDEDO6hGDY6bxPwqz99OH@weFRVtuVWEK7t3@Q1Z6/uJNQ0VtY@ilaR/@zw/27T15AhqcPD/efH3784NPDF08h3Genyyvk8sF9@Yy71vhP2WfCa@@tYZqGOTPNzulsdvqGvbasjgWtZ8@gUu7QY77ZgbpMjGW9avDrWb7x@rXhTehi73/w7fc/@O/e//Z33//2t9//9vd//MX3vw2/H8Lvu/z53X9bKeD9x1/8i999/1u/DYH/EX5/BL8f/fiLX/sm/5H/j@H3n2Nhfxz8Yun4TwBYv/jjL773Oz/@4pd@HX7/Kvj9@tXfL/9o/e/7P7f5h/m@97vXp/nuv4Pf73FYYdrv/hYPw@eV9L/F0/3Sr7//1X/P//80@EPnb7//1T/GW@D557/@p//5/bf@g6aV//TfvP@5773/uW@9/7nvvP@5f6q9/7V/o@bit999//0/@Ks//L2/@sP/kf5/SPff@5D/97/@z//if/2L//0v/jD4/Qh@/x5cP/qL/wBD5W//4Af4/70/@Ns/@gH@/8//@m//4Ff@9hf/J3L8Bnf8P//q3/L7X//yf/qb3/zOX/3om3/zKz/6m9/4g7/6P37p//q1//TX//3v//U/@xYG/saP/uqPfvEvv/Xtv/y5f/mX3/piw/3b196/@IDwL/4RQj4czw@B8yH1@rIhX/xU@Px9qLEsBfoJ9O5feP9rPw8d/FcZe//tH@KLrvDb8P9DTaU0P@S@/w84tKt1xpgcuOD3K@@//V0k0f8AJIL/iF7fiTwrMdzznaUHyPqbazL9wo@/@Je/Q76EWW3Q1hNO1mWtnNkBhWanUgkm7GBXCrL8/Cq0CEBQ0neQQ63EfQd52/sffPP97/zT9z/4jfc/@EWcraV8JbufldQbtvQgYeED0mHC4oekw4SfQ/mdDK3qSZnPwbf1eaGsO45T@/zzz4XOuYJvVN8@Z5/DH/s8vBiPwjeug6gwDsPxFWwG4c1Xr9q4DxwLU1QOXNH4M4jCY/pQkqR9lNlTVI1HmefKNs/FahCgl/VWDHVlMNipwh@DW7W6c5aV9log9FHWC8EMq6QGULcUphpZfUc3IKGS5@lY1bmdy2dKO4YBKnAG4WZI5tkJZbCCzuaZcNWbzYPV7zkmmu@Qc07L4XxNHO4C3ui/xFiZ6Yw5/L8msAwtlNOFX54NneQI8gVFcKdQgGIy0UYcFYzyFmHIQ2iTncrNVxjWYD7PzEHbBgeUkIGoOyD31@sZzFjnKIKXV6ZRZoRKJlOHemNunifbKSOI@R2CAjnrmWess1Of84wZhNcIyZERMOiZqGpiply/CwXW53cZwkLgBPbVq3qjXJ83ENw7Tp3MPHOHcEJg9cy88Q78dYIJ@YTE3XeASrmeyTTKWCBWkjdPtsMbqUCVo7pnWCZoA3jiuxJ7txn7SFTLIt9j2UKC8dR4zyxTY0JIDvGtzE5QHfoPnfTbIYJvUVFBKYzH75FMvMfFZEwAcCVJlmUGPzy8sMduQ/Scg8pQsfDIcAgZ6hHUA6IAhgtRGSFD7ZshD5SfqO986QuBYWW2t7eFREPUxScykU5RmHdcpRdH8CwlqjJVJhYrIgab9BZNiAvkr1H520nclUwyDph9lOG/27d32EdQTXouwwQmZXQ37yY4lN1MRtQAfsPNCC9B/xGgnxKgc0Ge12kXNCNks4zJ9QTGsSdPngRIUMDLupCBbq7pKvpxM242myUghyxn5Ww2eMr0pAA5cMgUGzzlbSTuqWdNTaZp@RqoaTWGQSyuU6mga2Pgu3fvoFXocFr1AWi5LDinpuXLFAkB3KCVbS/C1620fEXgSwBMLeYZS9FqMlxphu8VpaAjpQX@UgNHI7xSSa1cTlJKoL@c2gkPLhZV5AD8BS56v5kVSitewCbuxWVBvvaMW/HRm1Mcv1S5kA4jD56wgyePHh0@Ppq020zAr9vOpmZn4rk90/dTGLf/@C5//0WrFNOJZhOpclTVkCMJh9UcdtTMg7vPHjyvMk6loM1SVI8a7WIHdKmoQmIy@Ww3EZzzEvETpa74HO/VJSlSWgW4ZTrREBI9E1Ug6Hz4D7@a8Mgf3nHnLJXLimJWLaIKmsbdWMDjZ90ZQwPa3NoWDEJ8K0be3SUKCI0zKbb5gwEN9kwTuENSycH0Sjl0lLhDLRUxAT9LyXSh8fzwCEAfPWGqlpOFxudsLiNq0oXQsOu26Qyno208lCi2cmKs9tvNXBb/NF2Hu5ovZtVCqb21ZZ9JWFCL@sMZni69AO@ZhBX@KlxM@KrAvgpBcEEZeGSUBWvpD57UgkOTaNQyxU9OimoBRnBawP0ADk6YxK8aDJzV7TQhsfWNb0xZo3H4@K704J6QAEY0YuG5QcnqyyOZOkR/5pkUO2Ssb31q4Vdq5b7lT2xjAaMSqJG4uLgYAKQH95jW0MjLc/TxftGjkC64L@aGkHCq1fo7NV8Snu1Xq@90TRMgQNhR8GDiFnQVOt@xo/C/mg@F6HpZASaoiiI8dF0XqKMLVVNgdIbnXa5el3hv1fMqHeER8MNHxryuRVeQdv7RMq2e42kxBiLYcOqxXBhX4nGBryiQD4iGpxbxBLpQC8Z97tYtHRdi9HwuWnGhGrMLaJttPa8jxfGtsHYiXwq2mkRRbCcE25yyfh3ciRbc@KKipiZEhj7kR3o5JySaiabw/9cr2EXbnTT0nLqrTMBpgDO/qxjg7IKzsKt0wWmBs7KrWOCcNXQ1t6vMGgITdrkdbIZmturi1Jyj2X0eJjZ80x7I@JJYXaQCNHE3@K5EI8zY6Nf7bm@G53NqfdlyHNNDoxg8Qz4v1lwHLbTWw80rYGPpM2FYPyXTHYJZH8po9MtzDFvoy123v5D96cLG161s16snQfRNhhFL6CbIRLjgt6fr@WqTteWJO9kTtEIp01RzMJnhTy1nteyWuVcqVftyzzYNb69QLZSzfXyTK9ha3CvkqkP580cP70@nk2cmvd61l69ABjSTiQbt9srVQqHdbIpipknFtJu5tsz5mbS1BUzANPoSPHHn0Ze0chsy9y2vXk8m93RVk9SqnitfCEvCIc2xhg0Bs2awZlmk@1nAMqqO6wB3qmaNrHVGVKgOBoOLnbPM0iMYZxL3AX0uJCPbPYu8NSmWrspmWclaRkKIMQBynwV7qlVRK5TFWrO29JeKYq19Idwem33LwLe6Wrmzq7mKwMU51AQU1GLCRdVz3Wm1aw5cz1wm1NVimJAjdDVBXryIimvlsMSzq8UVY4nmZ1eh5AviRZQrREu4uAC6c2ID2QMj5w06/dxUK/n2IfAs6D67of1zTJZ4@VJI7Dz7VG80oKnP8iUtX8gXNL1YLJQ0mKAq@SIogDk1V8wVNA2g5CvlSukC@rWivEvQ503ZwVnY36v0gZeUUeUWipttln732LLPyrrE8Uila8AJE@@ExEfPPtUajc3KaAom9E81qVHXCxVw6ejSdMCYCZomabqkq5Kq4/8NDg3/Pzy9Bv8a3iGXrglHaLfsMUy0IEY47CHaP5q67MjFL@AN2R2ztyHFwcigs@kHnuv7f480dwznmEfdtbix8CjqvoGfAfXH1nS0IcWLyRhNnpnePxqEw3EXEER@yBPcgZtnu@66BCX24umGWj6KPs8BxODf54Dkzx58fP8o9jw63D@4LxTZnSeP7156FIJEBfbw8N5R5C3x2DBrIQLxs4cPH172Bo/8kxfPBjPXw59w78mL/PIWBeGrz0IertVEUTABCW7oJaEVZBDQCgul0KEK@MLMLdDUbwXOQnHpzKHzM/5et@VHL3DwV/yrwlH4srfBkNV2Tdbjlu1w6YCszgZqhVqqCMKEOe4pK@VY37Vtw2PuYLAFgSMDX1w1UVi2beyJWPSp69n9U6tvbgmP8B3ZCugcA0JCuA9AxrMeGU0B8QdtmMO05jDcjOvaM5PNJmxjIDwwCJ2eNRzBJHzqhgmErmEw@H3ZC/Kb8Wt6fcCUl0FhV2Lsq8kFUDDLBVE8EMX7xtSoeWbpZa5aferBZGz4Q7NxOIf@yl7A@DG8Rbac1cWpeI9VnZc72hA3d2x3gtqNP2mCkA/q2V7rr3/zh3/3J78yrAOXaeUOcgVcmNrde/Qwry0MLv8ptXegMY67542XrFAFdgeyMCNxNxCJZVKjtEq5UK7oWjlbrpTzBbVYKGRVLQsqa6kCqkVOLavFcqGiZsv5Cogm@QrEFkCf4QK1EkrQyk4VwDo9e9Y3d0kTk0egcvENWfY2ZaRZwoj8MyaakEcUUEuekmGAHasOsypTc0wvMYBosB5L3Lt3kLt3TxTvoAcPtBzkRLGPnkI5lyvdEUWTYg7KKGaJLs9TRmux4pR7crk7QPYZB4AfWhHFEXoOi7jOKIoWeg72793Dcgbo0TA/JDvmMdxjh54SJHPQA3I@AXgTQYNk@7ycPCF6iB4sEmPu8ZgDiBPFj0N0MOYZT8YB3A9rur8vig@4Z38fYw6o2gWO6NfQs0@XKHrggeEgikNwDD0YiKLYBScOClHsgau3MCBsDC78FoczNURxwcmDBBLFOaU2esei2AnDsZhPA2wKSN0qeVRe69vkqeCfKGoh0phMjzy6KOYjTx7qdv/@p8Zo2jeH/Fp4/NmDmt6/rxvWfHZ4r/vxx93hsOst9g8/foZRBwf3QURZzLzusBtk7HbgciHXwX3NOB4vLl9Q6wedTtWw10Z9rdPJG86lqM6iYyKGkOsNYBZcQyxo3DmAqIP7ndvGug11AthBfjCGZxevO2N43jG6PCq8KIqe825XrGH3V5RWSkAlAnfGcTgeA391smOj57k19M/rLJdFMWbRLObaNYpgY1AGcrULjB@k8G7g4lT6bNGc13Pt@rxeCo7CDVJia64VLDG7Nd5TK4XqlrGnavnMvIq2SdxBkiUldY@l1Fs7b1nqcXpPA8VAbO3tSWJTbe9parlaLL3cmYliuor3Pb1UfZvKJXOM4S3dLLX3SoVYjlIpYyhatVQC8QxoMoVJvotLQJ1U6tQ0jtNpxJaWGaAKVFe2oHpatUFqnp3XOV5ska7N62qN26BnuSvA@vjBk1lv6noc5BDAzfdyVTyFkRLVSlkEBBQllU5HTA@0fmG5YvPZ14@Oj44@JzGwEayAPPVM5F61wPvx/QP5wZPQh58qke@heOp68gFyrZUYLqeGQUegmMj3YWIFJS8Mw3dAPdeWD@kEI8i4YURoLU0OzIbLR/dX4Dwfuae8ZDShUSPbs07PZPglF6vPjHoDXEafpQgrZqRPaUrvNBr1Tn1MViagimGurzH6zMkSzAOf4x4Z9qDsZ/heZBDRqecuat36PDEHOJ06k9RXY7f/Ssv0an38gMud@h3MXOvAs1sz66bnuZ4IKrZYG@w59ZnjGwPzqemhyZoHT7ZBwMCXJVMDZqa3WesQUx@g@nIhNTzmLDF7PBunDKnRTa8G4TpgFIDESX09rPQZvb/bqYviRW1QZ6mXkPQN@L1tlurLd9J7@RrQ6Q7rpCEo92rwasA0VszXSP1IISwYSkQfrLfB0vXG1@DBYR9Xq4BN0NDHABULA8BWnyIg9cS6qPXqNktJbM7SRKR8bVhvYvZzvO1KotiWpOZ5W2hI0mdCA8ZrbZEw6v6sS9/@YrmuquWKtTmEqaV8bQTNa7yc17z6ZOaZNRu8waIgf1XZqAFRgXYA5u156v3PfzO9KxXqPKxGoM5RGOjInfq85qA1YegYdb0OEZlmPpcFxR5upSzM@VoxqxazejaflUoYChN@tpCFQNB7QOhI2SmRMTGbm@dkNauaajaVe2X1X6WzxykQZYhoLJ2duofObMwgBJoK@yZ54QnkyWg7NuhjfZcZuxJ1VmAZNawYUH3EJlZ2hKCemYZNOdJpiek7KXs7hWm2j2aTw2a7Wj2cT74OUSnpzV4xU8pl3qbTtdRWuu6bb4RGTWgge6FaT7ag5wbrpcyfjZvQyuBSS1q12exiFUu5rJ7ToXZW53y4KzbEdja3VVShiS4YsQ3G@UZ8CRElnmXYpIPyuG1C06kVrSbItJ6nlzWpohR2Cjm@pshzCpOAvSElWaolhq/lp5LJkpZMppM13CjZEoOFbuBpxM@SwF2Tt9Q9EYQxsSpWNEywZI305nUuxA7EsQsBJUWWB3X3TLg4u9htCF8RnuP7tLvaS/wrvXy0/wT/vgJBFfCWXz568eTFk3sCU@jQq9xJ1LZqcq1TA48kN24LiSpjwElbgc0wZYuxL3ucNrPbeMmfLXyTA@AK9IWAJmvTMTfTQl2OfYr2KPZYEupgeOOmpuntplaCuQ@4aZhU09QaYNFJ4LsicgMaY34G@O1mGvgq59fYYmFkpHAB4Fa1Mcxs57RF4qQjFis6fyexoeaO2Vby1g4DcUZiiZPjrYa2k0k@reqZ5N2knk@cpFrbjYy6SCpsJ6MtBrhbj7u@ShLSaebOR/pO8kWmWh5mq2oG7xrcq0kmbSVud7K30xVfoCZhiUsrEvv1/eGz/fB04P5Bo6wtgldQEy87YrkUoNjaBpJpmZeruRsw@b7EZfeWgC8aJBNnSZZIXsCfkLhNr7lq/DVXlohedMXd8mAPSc8XWTpRSQe@UiXhp6INnK8kbyeSuE9S9f13CepS4VuEX3ulQW9OOG4YACoerr/BbFso4BZBQnk18b@hlfVHD544d717ppBobZ1vubi1w2oR@u@cT77O2AQInGStemJezwen9tVGQ1J3NTTsV2JVmFAGalHKnTf4kGlQRFGDmPc//@v5@S7oQEzLqeDXtEJGazTUHQ0qNnn/xe@jiaazw0/3H7IkLvP/3Z/8jlb6uz/513S4L3lBS/@aXkpASnSqxVLi7GxydnYBF48rJNqJK2ca2kAfRTUqpR0ZaqOUDXB0lASnI4hQJTWd8KVEcIizWJBSKVXR0jt6OZeGmPPABFtKy5XBG@6TUZBYLIjpxOEzq6Cpt3f3oGZ7el6rbUFbqtEryyz62zX9CiqUj16dMwaeXqM/HFoauRSFVd9Ju@@YtMve4RbVO2mLvao38EyGii86hxszO/gqJe57JhsZZSfJQPVijeZF7aKdoZ0dUlxf7jitS3RobeF7OqtBOw78mTs@/ZkmeSnAB2/oM3de@2JqJ60o/b54dZlu12SFBnSVHWX5OjbbCfdr@J8ktdLvf/7XNK34d3/yy@ed887nGqivlUpR1RI/@cnuzJn5Zr/xEwBwjWGeUAUlKRQt6KAjUl0Zt11sBbkih9wDrXnmoJjO04eKLKquDEQca@iYfVJkhRMUy6hlO9w2ZD9FyXbQbkeWxHyyxZauCUIoD3Mx3hv2sgSD7aDB7WY7LZwJX8UomPUZqAI14atLUBAwhnne7XV8e@ZN6D2nFOVT21l2C7JACV9Fu5tbZG8kmDIk4J3KztWsHGWfqEYiHBubvo9WPGG2E74KWYKvEtgLNjHQNA6mtByYo2RMQnhSRL8JZbehbJtn6FBoimrPE2QZx45nckDUF74KUgtRwQJhhlm7kKAGbOWrQACoQyoAbLXZLtPT7MzKZGpLE6EX@D4EvvdjhGY5BMyG0PpoBibMXMN0EAQqBn4HG/tF0MIgS8YCQyAcBj/VUAclBbOTD@VDspvzwaAAFtmoS1HV2K1bS6zqdaufZlQjhH9sTXDZjdrBWY8rAAsVvI/6VTHL0PhqLQyNuh1QPEPoQq@TuNXVWiwrE9F7IQjw/8GdFnvkpaaiiBpWIGgvPip6QDLIjGTnbdhju3WmaqU0i5DvAe49QoqMI0Raa2v@kax9HkZeAIY/SYRfmQOmdRRfygz67WW7LAxk@hl@4gut83FmENhT4fb3kPk9mIa5o1xQFcum1APLA32KjluEpj9TuprGbEtTqYQHvbGg5Rm@OFBI44NyYWoGTwNNWAblbJHprZ4LDepPXIdsXpJNLnxrA3oE8KjAXCBHe@ac4ichg7ahzHGMfDIViD0fMSYbni4aN6K8eHyh64HeHdImy8yhzHrjPtMqLEUdjcwaOhG4NGUihLsgliONu7Y5BpSemya9behXFWUIotqsS7YdH1nQr0b3LJiBHF@5ywmsnFrHlnKEttkld4AvJXJLOQmU7nD48fMPgR1F23WPmW0dm3yFOrViZ8hnoJiAbJ0Fyi5/QNgqntnR9Cyuj6hZngp@JXiUuLOcjeXdSi3SV5@6upXqYIue03xjQavY5onhxOhL17kQaOT@wg8tlZG9LfDLEcs1AxtF9SRaH4mMbwmBzbU6mfuScedjkhITYmirDJ3CxDNPGOrWAs4xwDR7odUfHMVQ26/SBEBjD0YWmjCdelW0VQWYeP1UD4ZewOAd9hHTNQETckNygdE3gIFNX1@FDnGQFevhT/vQMDIt9yNfgdE57kMcWkkJuh/mD3s3usm87LJ7s60AHE46VFad8WERegoxD44O7M9U9S2ILAKGazDZSokZAJsR0yIHHeW/nJ33doF4SZVdhZRlCCEgNUAhUcFAloM2KmPfbhQg4o7h8w/8BAZOT09PZbK6O/Ms2fTxe4a@6xi2MhlaIBG7ytQcT4Ivx1s9ZRLCXbok/hlTeTKa7M1Rrq1Xbi34UxAGfj04yJRKDvwkTo4n@Lm@4Zgs9KFpPJ861D2LPvXZSwXnqnj/09rZs7D/VbH/SeXkBQJhDMHMs4tsLwvAst3ecXZw2q8FESc0IAE4tKIZBqItbC/0jP3QZU0GUQp3inw0iurax7SBDJBEvpC8LJrXMEy5CL2Bf2LNIZNjnrJ9zzMWKYpPY2rswKkFiT1sAdM@xYATP35wxg0zW/Pmor2SfR5lh0ktOj7hofk94ex6oNxKN8bPefwc4uc8fr4sNCy2OW9zkQyDLrA62OvRamuYEsEswjQX3KL1MoYggzzOVA4CUy5Wwi7g16tT7pDe3AftWA87BvSJCRDcTCnNl61mq@345ulOO6MMobOLRAhocQDdbBNNT/uRG6lvn9gT118JctBYL8xKAd4Y1BsFvYH3Faxj1EDUMTi9LLSvOhwH5zy4QBBUGCCgHAaRKBrsT1NWuhaZhadI6DhNcUljjlgzQKZN0lcQFYSBuMRJzwkbB9SOAcLwqEqAJsSwcOTwr9eG3OEzz4U0YVqJPrg5Rjt/yXYSKHlpqHBeU6NGimElSSGaQHYUV@uXqxLGQ1M0L0XFqnkRtH8c/a0vjf4AxsV67KnD8gmjJsSHCp7aBBEiGC5EVdaox9oVMFB2DNv0YOY65PJpMFtDMTtKqGbwcrAK/qk17Y1SscbvpXn70FuroiNWo66wqNehios6H5Z8XIQk5QSPsvlBtkXYEYL8nIEAjNzabGaQbR7PNq/XOeNg8w3ZTmNIzgnJOc/CU883INkOsoH29CCcXrB52iCd4rFSEeCpfBoFMWgiMt84MXEz/jXaIMXNi6DMJc@hXhD0IRSxsZ/12mtLb8aQjjGtSwCwI14BAFKIMbOnVeEyw/t/u/u@9bZxZM9r8ykQ2WmTMfXPSZxEjtyRbTnRdGLn2E4yWcetpiXKZkeW1KL8R51kvrN7sS@we7@PsK9y3uFc7VPM1q8KIEFJlp3uOWf2256JRRJAoVAoFApAoaqcT94SGSWkNDJK3jQbiKwgBmMRvC5@ut2EyXgNTAp/boXnARq7uZUjJ1fmDWj8ryT/cr75aP6Vpz@WsjnL2Y8lf@J//yEfj0FZa4Ba2ke59AgCGSuZdz3t4NbWORZV7YIWOKTVnVz1lTtD2abvxQtdtHjS7Z8UzwMY1SA8tnwtDMaeWT/gCEe9GPRHwaj/6FFFFk0Rs92s@mXNEJ32@oiqZ/nqJ12v3Q/j3vKIOrXVP@1FcegruFH9HOplR6ijhzi2nqwf@7HjaPsuWcYCtPAVVN1mM@pFo2bThdmkV0nMy9mKEuy5vOxg/UtPVnkSTxro3sDtn/watkbe7TAReEIXO4xan929gU6Eq46aIhnWIv2fUs9Ig1FxP105slN7qNInI5djqZz1z/unpPVdxAXswzoT4BspbCAUDAaMi68CLGkrVvgRHiVuyw88XfSn7y6qflp1Ay8pv5oFkCGGr4aTNAZlhzOqa95YnRQz9R18P74HNr4H8/HlVfgkzrI0r0ri91X90E0hUMYUjYe3o4Gmk9xqT6GTQSX5DL1KCtwZxTYbrbWBaY2y1nT2Qof4w0/eYnpLEH9/E/3nd6ApXr9r9wU07NXBmOTNOQxAxc1ObE5iXcre8CB7pqtLWHv7jnVRXsSg3oEKQWosC64e/HHTwETUqjjZQDaAb@F52IlN8T0bj1UlcQZOw0tffV69uYu2m@2wG4zDtqtz@hZc0@J9WrCxvLpbwyHoWOj1Za3n0tzlJak0jYPokqlyA8sE/qXn3cxWkiVKuId3yhnDxs30Q/qUaMYWX1V2q2kdsLy8iO3Yywjbn4jWJSEfuhIFU8tRmX@kJ@F543aCEB1k9iz7abXePPG57yZNusOMkOQtZJsMj@wGInxqTffh95Ho9pZS51qFqqaXnWywo9k9Hs3rcYsrDE/KsdPdWPI2prszz1msJsBSEbb1fVPIFGSYj7Rarg1RvsztsX5vSibgG@/T9W6YVZozBGpSkiXdKOLlNusXnoOVcYN@seH0nn4B8DQcNYWhTNuwp6UDSytOOQ8Gltaiv5CSTlAsKgrJNRpWLsc8U/Yv35I6WzfW2Zqqs5WpMxkB2SqtTE4rU6XuBXTPvC7ohp3RDdIZSVg70888sU3/9frBELsVX5aj5Urkq@XL5QoJ5OVwuVJ3SSgvt5cr2/wQL1cO@OHzcuUnekjH1vLX5YoZFsgwpFd@eIHvWoTjvbVc2XK9b84o@BzGpt7CciXpU8rzo7wyRYgUaDdpjThi6/V1M0fDkCY2Vip9BY6JfSyfeB/G538l@r@EL@PARkjEHucDzqxWVDkzaVgzhtRD04YJnDFjJFf0bF7f22HzqyQLqlmhNZ5dhsGTGr64nBVGghhS@USDfglByM3KbIyUNZPdER1dO3Eod3K2fokWyfpA2@X0I8p8nFbCMet0edNfWRDSgXfDE4VvwnMKHVMdY4QzWW8GWiDqL8tzGoW@zuKie9/uId7rzmYibPMmi/QSg7VkOulwfDjH8Tb7gyyTcCpM/yO7DG/KyaAE904UY6mgR@YNyfxZtwyCwR783rzmWOWAWkYEIfGodCyjLJkXWBYjKZV1lqYqg49QsGQOjfCw9ZnjAW7rR84n4sbnueKmaciUlSpZcmXFJBUuwJPYRTCS2pPFax3@xb5v@WpKXmOvxQUAq2RSi8jX/nfo733R341CbYgwUcEsxXr2VDqtXs@dZScw76bVTncgEn217c1UjpIaUpLT6sDSzOfx2pSKD5MPUfKl0gT6hLZvyJasCW6h2@TaQmBBSxheZj9@XqWPn1dvJtS0RtK9LBilpYCaNBxpeIJp2rT5uErDZ3UxUnh/O@h@dwcPsx1sdx7gcQOGEySXUT686LGVSzq2SWzLF4jUckWJIOfj0qSb048k7vnoNjm2pQ97zf3tvd3XH2nSffLkiafn6HGKH0Yt9lqTeVwgsy13Mh/MWLas@gjahcNubMfHZ/3h6N6nXm5KloiwJmUgoFoM@@kx7mlZZsnzibFL5SSvRVEN63M6DIKMVIKqE2DKjjRdR0SQcOQ@CDQQo94SvX1erXkcnqrZ7AXnYbPJ01ezCeOlZlPPYugacyLu/X3xXvEiHnLwd4mtduU47GlDbe@pD69qh@rwVV3tvNv6SX3ce6c@1HYP4Qnh7bvN140tRf/quwd15WRM8RCHEgtKout22AoRXVitlkqPFEPe6g/GInfcLU@@HwTn6lW/FeKY6nkcnL84k5dCLxxtSKk6LUfH2MOMOO7oeTSCvQUHyqRlLJSbNl9XxOUDRXlPaE17jjXveb8ddSLK62DtO4jC2NxwU92IepDkrbnl7YuShJiYbDrEsW5hgXVFxQPKj7MbAhOI/RVIjBwSRLNdUJpwyX/fTcHD@v6bAwX3G1t7u9uNw8be7oHa2dun17cfG7sviZ6Ng8P9xuY7JHHGN3vbjZ3GVo0/CAKlgoJfjF8v4tFcFArIzlRpfcbJd2FA3Z@8ZXe9ocGrq4AvbsZq@aIH6RMF3ej3sL287lzEUF9wWZSPCpS7VNt/@Z7mfBX@hhNOcxTM9ge5dzHHaV0qqedcGw2WDRpv63q40rSXL3t8HnE@VgjVFK6zFwyXn31lgLMRTzsKVW4LNirY@xZnGTyWDWiq6B7BBihjsFJVHGJtedl/ziA3qLZWtw/vrFKbGBHqFxR9YUxN1h2mmLaVAVBcr2j0sB9UXk8@EN/Th1Vd7WgoGdTD5INkUI/kA1TRBmxH1GOd42K0dwHxrNbkw6/ngx0@FlZPkg@bAa9in2qcpN@4SwOVhKiE65AuB9KTXR4O9is@Y1Ak5vwIMtftysAIJbwpyUQ5SmTbNsqZI2HTwVGDNnuTsOFIJW6AnVDQGcXKrXoFdQjjoLAXSQjD027QExOo1HSHeU89hQOoqr4XHiWh//jCyqDPDIiwo1k8knLbWisM71qOSm5O1RhoG0kOv2tM0G5DYHMKgT8ChgDlMyudFs9UfJcWYPodzcpu3CeOxL7t3@z8xM7ti1aYKaCtttxfo99/9zSR/cw6ydgpMnbURb@HQ1Ir@Siz0x/SGGexysHSIAVbZ/3BKJI@dLMt4BMnnuYoNyY2qu2X6kamNtBhssZev2dVekJcfEOtJ8SUd6mVOV7OzhPxlUbRJs6nSVjs7oBOcNK/DK2zMx@HSFchtl9IEeazcmx@jkeMieifTio7/qYQfPdpdWN781P@b7/4iMArYkECYBujQ/wjxkRdNDz4nI8NFofQu/RIM5ET44sTlNY2eFpaYpQbYLQOPItoXfeiuZ6kibnx9Hdc5pn8zh@/fq1KqTwkk46aHp@5qXTz1ZGp0ucyx0qbgFiyk5AlWe@aLz7DTOT1C1zgQS/A7VAPcgTr9om4hFqEmNadXHRIsujw0Lq7E/ie2mCLCqNIisMIuz@KP7ub1ZUNr5galCiLnK4R0b6BXPY8yyyF56spcNvzwZH8vju4p3Oxk@nhu6Btz4X2XbjlV26GJdOSBevuYP82B6xMbn8ILLXdvxmwTJLT0BJOT5jTX1pMrGnn1/jLVN/x2CMwmHuxg5IAtWq76PERtfF17koBzwaTKkQHh9v1/X2Vk/UJlSW5hyVDW4tBwL6n3qbWtlGPhV0hUZqSxXKiPJkvGYs289@8wTyTeDeICq2D@JoeibBI7uPQgu5apJ6eWViFYOt7FoiGclnsvhgZFB9pwN9oDUjIpp1mNdCZ2cxFmXyi2DYC13TzRTe2bfjZwlrmbgRdHo5tQLZNUHCKmyWz@@@D6McVU48oWHC9hAa3SZOm@YbWCQdU8YAyFgrZHpzTLaZLYWQvCvaioR0Mv0pZDfvPMxQzkijhogtbYl0rxxo10Y@XjJrDBomYBgJYeupEsWimBCPi@ctzu0O9dNJzs1MQKZkIw/vC5goqfvxNT2FMjWSerCYKuT3WlhibI4PlMXZnNez1mzPdhy302qR4mKyKpO3cqvL/mKpklsjUZGg@szEmkSCvPX788DbYk60wxfN/FrbMIZPyc3Q@oPV9CjIex7y9T5zb2PVNesoAc0gnpvVmwEwUJFVnxpySaTtPRjZ@hIvsCxEyiBeAyMaTtXrqegK32dBlRrKhc5apNlhDOGmojJop6n@bXx0E8q313fv@@mSwIRNMB7/BKv9NfxiH6a08y6OM9Qk38bPfwuGwx9nkPtM5oLh8jWnuZTu@bScGr9IqJPJ5m92Sjr6dJGa3vtlr4Ep4e7GAYObY3Vuf3N7Ll9ftpu40XtfVA3a22cnsReaGOc@SPfei3jwEWAbzvgSmD77Ddz@u0D/CwTcgiUx8m89l2ni34sYUIa35iCNIabNQLVvLk73fiVtBDz5I/Nz9WOX8H6gg78LW93a8WTvrpfVMeUIuHvRcKuXn8oUcF6Vv2NAFpCwI6U18tyYs3NQwlpK4XnPah30UDrbCa9k9Y8vJoFh@Wlp75nDrev7IPz96duw/aFVziibfoHceXwyv2p9P@2eXHdVVg19Prlvj339T6vEjONtWqz@IM@XyWrXI7mifKPjhflZiztUI/siOoRFcuyBRh5VaVuk6fP2e8viBF80V3JCY4FL14NxwIa7YjarnR2vH1V61tH5@1DtexyW/0Up1tFJecfHhB5pFScbIyfzR6Bhzqr3rGvYuFfyKcnRbfTVE8dUQ@vImGEb917Xdl5ndOCgA2ALTtt68oS6BzBdgzYa7J4VeeOXqbTJfgWMdKEjOAt8KKuPSO@8nYzumHRFm1Cs@abPxNf8de85CqXAxGPU5xTiFBGupr9FXZ8FcYyrxjgJlOYqM60jcLyA4aR4XB0PydSxW1PmyqGtl3J30LBBHKMniMPcpl8OdQiCq73IdHTtxIQxaZ0CiS2r1Vy6mnj9XeCNWiwu8iwdTjmDIFyZKx3jEAQj9DPi0AVWw5h7ztQ@Hmo/3Mh7kC@9RjfieDBvIO6wpIgXm3@oL32/i8s@JAEL4BdG5CnqLU2tepEjK3UHeXIDDtezCH8cMuFYpnbKAxgK21FdNgbOlONMI1Woy0feFK5BTaEX/6Rbky/w21YwkvyfZmSR8Tq3fYtCSu5STNvDTTYu5VrG8KWYyW6RYuJUa2Omi5dGbkIbVWG2F3S4hLbRYSMmBR77fq@tfSeqPj1DncYK8pOen0vOZ9IKkC1JprgJN8Gmmip0pt/glzfdN5dJs/lRdVcXKS4F6ulUglSTNuz4vb1wY9ZtRmnkj6UrhyiTheSYhb6X8PKP3JeVepkzC4En6kaRr/l7VPZ9gmcn7Ils/fh3dQSEbz2pbkwkuLfSi7o@ODvquU8BmOaKmUlKcQ28qM6iq@g6mFiekwWGfn4ftRjWFslI2EofHTG7j@YtcQSsZP7qTaMgtxqmBNWOMWFTiOleYcNd8YZHq4eR7FgiGCUZTZuRumMJjXXhsgUWue6ZauQU5NcCpaZNDvIp7kV/xxwz2LHIm3@LsxAXB/FoaL7ebswRioXsvN5tMWWmC6yLyUTdqziyS1j2ehDhbSOxau8BJnaHcwe5gG/xeIidsQWEkxRTdkxRN6TRD2bDvTV2IxG/O34sPnJcB6diDbnitalhmBHwLy8lccB@F8SiGFyp2kBNfDAZdnDqywnfFV6h1fIDVxzhuSSFaM3vBacCyR/L7eNIX0qlQQe0B8hUMRNKE@OL0FJfJcAO2fwXRih2XaFRwar2xbGjQmHm4KtfMQwXnGyyAu9GpjYT0nIweUDoeBK2w4JCOFpP240hTO5GOWMv76bg3AmdnNKVVHOdfLqLW562XOM99Ui49LFsku9THwaXCw0fpBSsikklYhb/Cx@VHjmOdDbfkbDgPgL56jYn@PfFmeBn2eqFToxmDM8aktMbh8DJsFxxnP0wOgQEXrIyTSdzD7l8MW7K5Q0pXQMyIW8KxL8dhxGH4xfwsx8UtPivzHRxapafN1NWXURsENDdOOn2cDvOBBdwECD1Q6DwcEVEeeCqLEp89a1xYdznHRhRRA35OrLOJhAy9/ihqUc/wTpbTJVByDJJW1mtPYEL1tboBLgcXZiGA6zEpBQwC5ihpHg6OPjT/LhyUbpg5Yw9MzxRJ@vV5rNBwD4cRSd@UwNwrXMzCnTr48FXjQB3s7Rx@qO3XFT2/3d9739iub6vNj3zGjYNy9gasXu29JumSnKbLqfkefcjVDqhkjhOc2u5HVf/r2/36wYHa21eNN29fNwgagd@v7R426ge@auxuvX63zafvBEHt7h2q1403jUPKdrjnc62mmJOWU3s76k19f@sVvdY2G68bhx@5xp3G4S4qw6l@Tb2t7R82tt69ru2rt@/23@4d1BUa5mw3DrZe1xpv6tsFqp/qVPX39d1DdfCq9vr1REP3PuzW9xUbCVit3KwTlrVNWsKiJm7ndmO/vnWIBqVPW0Q8QvC1rw7e1rcaeKj/tU7Nqe1/9DXQg/q/vKNMlKi2a29qL6lxjnsLVahftt7t1@E@CZQ4eLd5cNg4fHdYVy/39raZ1gf1/feNrfrBunJe7x0wwd4d1H2FYJZcNcEgalE6PW@@O2gw3Rq7hzRnvHsLewePOvkDEYawrFHRbSYwzCDQWiLS3v5HQAUduAN89eFVnb7vg6ZMrRqoAIuKrUM7G1VIRDy0m6l26y9fN17Wd7fqSN4DmA@Ng7pHHdY4QIYGDDI@EutQpe@41egnwkseiVkdw7k@d6dq7Kja9vsGMNe5iQMOGppbmGxbrzTNC/AMbG2iRH3sGQTn9sZKZ/rTZQhfmNM7MrP3aBKPSVt723WakbWzq1ya8I5mnacTrpTsNJppkkR6zbisaYcnF6fNqNfp445pUkw2Ps7jUx@RkzxEkfnkzAlcpvdXuMDiYrP5vtakhe5Bs@n5dymZQeO2EnobfF4uT7cRoSCw8sbGT6UidH@eIdTGD/qgkw31cACBnEL9H8T0LTgPPVUstkNdDJf3AdhsHcVybHKGoxQSjXzZEeFv0ip5Z4LfI80OXNA14AutJvZJYRnJmfox/el9TV9kcrA@kHSW7a5iEYtYRiP6PTTVSCXsEoH/aI8EUYerLMRh@PnULdnVYc1fOO33267nmTKcd0TrwFPXu6X4SXg6UTw/WZ6R5WNnHUUhNutuVmGS82dNMqX7pTDklrn40xzxj2ewEZ8P2DXlqnizWm9auj9IcVgk@Uq7tsD1Cu5k6Hxvan9tfMBqrrT6aH3i@6vku4wt2AvCay5NeEdc7ph/Xh1LBhpg7IuDSBJpDxnFolXG2Jskma8o4xkyXUVtWP7QXH0W8rxOJCFF9iLo2nViNh5G1zb2JIdf7tfebL7b2SHRCWwfPX38ZG3dSdxu/dWX34@ohx3bstexAc3jpKdxkjVKtkjx4ZFi@RVP2Z8ZuFhERniRN53GH@HnIbHbyFoyQZChuTFiQfVgopcLQYecYgcc9xzDrzNHpmYAN9NUD605D65ZxQ9IV2Ie0MYs3TH32jX@AHYy/M0QTxqkGUizGLv6Jc6l1QXLvdyOMRXlxQ077kGWQs7wsbhxS2jAW11sP4vbtfymedvqxVhMGTFeudu5JCFxbxILZewqejKy37KfEb0BzN7D6MtfNb/R40ft4I7d3QXxqDY6IDLuJCWxT51uRutGH2nIx4jqAadqpqbnCrv8nkaKx57eTk4cg1ijgVFBjBrY@GYBryd@RCarZAvYF8ue@iKcCucdgLOuOVa/E@fOao6Gsm78h@h345VCCazEyYlQ7SqpwzFZPiZ@LAw5M2T6U/Rg@P9EmsyA/5xWnAQ9pZblBPBOlGSoQitavjJRoitz0GCdbqTUtD99TMF8szvmLGmYPr25lvs1RALdO2Pz4SO7Pey4MwgAJsfGhj1@E5O0s4CWTi9yni6Oc5Je63zgKj1XmKliCm5@7dhntcs3Zyt48ZQne01Wha@pqHohC7cTHvW0ZJpYyqv7cU7Aecb/R/EBb4AkA5659EysVic5q6RHmZED2tWSNeG0E49JpJZ@u/HU7oGyXGRmZL8@@TKEItAbwGe6nRzepK/EPDfrcZFnYnXIXvDgvhzLZEw@2mXdCRtidkPAud/mzRBEQBldYYLoCnR21ZdCU@59NhRBJanVYepnEOLWKxBpeVq9SrDnnUlwaIL9u554zg9lV8vkKIiDD42hfV2@oN4EY0K5e7dmC4sVHxz0fdguojLZltDlEe2l1e8PSXUM0G7C0Y/GXkF90JsOYS@@GGr/hTSfRUO9I2GUfqoGapOs3nmaEZf1jFocjXBboV1g/uAmnYewEBX3JNf5NeUS8xoe3TCbjtH1Slm5z9OU50QTdkvKRHyu1tTXr5JLCKpdhoZMwShOFhdss8n14NwhGX5X/eFnzP1QgXrtsJ14JrVA8l6gdFKjxz4eWyNp@qAf844GdQV2QBJKlGUjLTFUpTn6iWYnbdeUS71jwncpt@T760mY1FhLUUUp4@raifnW8tSZoNKqdg2aOAstrz5mVGYtuL7duBhjb6HZY2uV@9RLREpFlIjqfaM64knkZvL0EU96k796P8booS8449YqKBCGzopz1Wk5x/jBpuBDFA7b9p4oaTLtYIDtN1769HvMi2brULv9awWjOBzTCqBVjK6LDKPp/qV/1mtu9bvBadSPAlqnwd/8tUg8PI75ER12OuxfxRzISMIyWpna4/RZ/MuIGza8J@eS65ZrrngUDlzbTGE0HNfOxE0E75zDCDAN0Mr8PZj0kZaUefQ4LeRk75@yPV7ZW7@x7MPyrMJyog8AWsBtTFhQyB3SEV9Msi6frk9lOJmXwcLxROVV4N1gsZfB@BmRiI9hMhgbZKbMEuxGYGV2I8ZH7Wu/zT4Ih3C0FG6HCMATu/zZDxAkm6TIj7AUqKjy05JVVE5RruGHEA/jm8m9@uSfjD0h8CfQLz@cxS2zGIFFXMd4W4plvaK9jBIubB4YsYxmSUxSLDqNetb1Q452cT0JNZs8vokabPlDSpF2szfFlRiRLi18EG/PbZLIaY49TCrLatljvx1QQWojt3Qzw4a32c/y4MchruycQTBtaciuhfRNpGoRlRAreMK81kZZfCrfPmJWV@/aaxMErM4yObPCYbs5o7nwDZRI5lcca/WHJIxzE9TTph7L8ag/WL4j9W6UHTM9s82idcvzbjUEFmar0mT5oM2krY7xOF53JvGZYJosxdjSjHgIy1d@Tth8kojX1SbGW7U5voUON9EstZtKJpWkv9sy9jEpXsKi10w0yZBi3OGkdD35ftSkhjdvliAapiyvmiwxmhAZzbE8WqAmyJRQ6e4UYu7TuE/Qo02UQ71top3dPzcSddJIzrg8NUkZJ5egJxy349ImyaVBB8YXcBMnGm4ipBKF89of81FeOX8CJ8NIEIDQisN8ug8lO7hpZ03wEUcH6LhNWAuVIYnoacO2cEic/icEY6/8enNHWzw0x/ny8bpAuk4g0aqCc82DZO6b0@tR85qhTJGChvgMUiQtmpJNZ3dv1Z9tC@UjCFKak7Wlb8lHYzy1QtjQHzupeQ0dOK1Kl8yMqOxAaLJooLFAq5TTbijLVWh/0VA4HtYNehjRAkI@u/hZ0SXgznutlFAbRa7bY2TxNLlltHkqvyFFUoaSd5BfD0VRdXnhSgBCwZjKV8sEAW5NGXscCrDrHZvzMojqPqKC1TKGJX1kr6ipneeMdBBVZ3j02MpRmpXjmQ0jPxMIKRaz86SIkM4yO0sKhSa6mbhYOZ7Mbk@agxRiw/tCceoK3StZGiY9JwTkmNclL5UoR2XllzQHc@Kjx14mMeFvTn1WslJLk6lEnwTDo3x5MvVpKZOaqXZ1NVs0U5Lo4dm1ZhKJFJ6NcCIV/tx/fDXFdnme2IRai4yMlqHtsxGTnFaZtG4r/Bqr53wp2@gYBp59M9wsv5oSYiXjlH2@A3a1zEcG8N3@p1trLFMNJjpWAPulM5ddXFkQssaaw1SPZmGlazztJQ4KzJq231HvD3d2Mm5fT8bG0Og8HD4ulUpg4hPb@b2xrcZWUtQvZnMXOxfdbnFw9Zfh@5Miy/4w5JAAFbOCDqlLaFDEhf7wVCJDAAfKitx5fZEVa/2LTscOwYATSnQedZvk1N4QFE9AUWL08v6QN4AYpJ5gf0ED0b5fVDL6rgJRNDUUcwxFpWESfJkzp2dEHnzowD47OaliYBDMxpqJ5i2vuvEFMwgim3Bnsfti70tqnpx7FXa7fV99QChkeApY@DZZYGfHLlCSLDhh5Nu9FzH7o/VVeBl1rXvFyGLzOsCZicnEmTB@4eEbfz88rV8P3NzRzzmaVqjJK2jmCvxT@yp3mvO0s/g7gBU@JLTvlPs8GLgtptNkZprq9QhOnwijh2V/5tonk8XjPTFNs9tzg6iz0S2wswZquse6gPFlz93LLbkhe0Lc3Kfrcgc0LAkMjRN8rtytBK6a/fPE4uWo07mbVOQwANKx3yURJRLKnxOIfAbAI1APP6InvGj/lKdhvTPhUEQUHATrmJY7KNBEAce536r@duXWajW1NFhZUbXaJj3k86q2WVPb@LC5qbbpfRPvP1RXHz9eF5m77X2hj5vm4ze1STB4h3OldTbcpldKq@LeGKy10cVLxeqSv77UrD7fWI@LR7VNXOunp3//r//93//b/yjW9Mv/wssmvxz9nGQqFArFpdaXpR@@reP9aPt4eenkaGlwvHy6Di77O3sN7zdG@SA1Hy0MT5xFmQWsr2xHatbZ7H1GF1Umpt95MPxM0qWiFltxcVF/jSVyFMvYxVZofQ9xj/KElvAm6MDkUp6QWCSgY2zHU@@0Qhjg0XxDlCRcYAcq5eVsxWzcwx1MkiE5VVnUnnhYZ70Mcacl9aSAu7g0Y@WjXhz2sAN@yTqvNM9xAvqNRk3Nv8Wf38Snm/1r9eCTqx6U1ANfPcjl@Ke89oy@ekvFCLdzJRstB3I5n1LSowWYGao4YkWP1w8ca2eC3I6zxCF7AMm4qeDMcgvOT1Z/fFlGAq7Fp84CYn4q2SLhQyYUWfyy1PtG3fKFcnzLZa7asKLQ1KsYrsw6UUn6FypQEIshQFrzuRCk0qcqcdLHN5LxVDRfdF87HE2IAYOs@y93eNzjA81FSz1t85xZSyHMEZvPy1fMjetyGZrRRorUnyLAByqynCzxTcLlxWVHrLytVnIz5Ra23T7NfGLrMA5HxjZdCv1NWUwg1tw24ZZ6@l6LNuSW4xWVi5LjFauq3KTtt3KsIucX3VE00NcVuHYMqC9Jbd9kJKFHGZDAEZ/9lekRxhsFxlPURLdIsKyxavfRdBkJPX01nTrYK8jJkUWE4s8uje2vE2PbK/ItEcMOwgOMVGLK1wmibqy9rgyZ2KfB8ATRAYMOB1QbybkZ7@chdusExv1OgnSBIbPJeTqeqSmLg2Fweh74anG3fzgMxg2atkjzGbUKHrUQLpiABAafrnpW8wzC0iLdJUyRpClsOYTgBd2xDo8mfZtL7pygS81Q0G5XMAgy7MSUDL9m@mqCjilXf0cn2ChPCe/kNFKLWJa8sDTSkHL2tRkeZlNDxzE12GMnGTg5R1BNRqbhBV3oAhPtOR/8kiTvwkeArjunbwHqqwhrz1A/ZqfTsBdkJqdB1zEX/YvrSuZFjGcORSnWSI6G8qScRrwDVqRH/pz1AiFzk3Fn5Cy47sKnWIdzW7TnEXbyndjiFwMVJQHoOIAZ3wxR73qRCMuJGSqNgVFQDbb8JwidbnBK@I2vgjFY8dOi@@O9onf086fe8QP3U@/rp989xkSLZDPL5tWiPsw2EkuPFZoZi37m1VilxcbV4KdeNsOnnpI7LBYJCJGie/Rz8fhrkRD6tOh5D4qfFoUgmS4DJsX59RUBvjiF5mIWi@Kis@A98Eznuz@WPUVzK/@iD@WDJ7@EhVlU8jY9rXOGHQLF93R/u5ArJ3Hx6Wrp0Wr5Ea2ETsPr/DC8wHybjy9OwmtSJWIsZ2nq@fR7hhsyhPh2HQfr9PGa2ilhTeTuSawvKWkRqoc51@MkbEVlCsITlJ@ozO5SccXFS/IEOHzEgt9XxHImL/uCEtNBi/tczJ9x/xz1BDHk2uTtEOFIWBmIjQhvoeYB2QRfuYlDPTNclvmeU0FtwXcrA6HuLS5as0Wv38trZc0rLK9Dicatme7T0tPS5BidGqKZEbqklanle6q88eOTf/ufe78tjhY3VosfhvQ7Wvxtce3pojzSA709NG@XixuLz5Ft7dviuEhrYHp88m//m8pv/IXgIGX8nP5sPDaw1saLG/kqF/m6uLFGD@XVVar3//zrv1IblmTFhlisS01fMWLrhiJbQY95l9JVA62UZelyKlb4YhZgiIUhrc3pBYZR16tPS7xNt6itKi5D7fnK2KPoKZ4Ns0ZsKiQ7GcaegjQjKVBFBXkBaUwoOsqy3TBmG2DeFE31y/3CWkwrgF@0OUdSZWK6cT@GydCSLIuoA12pkdbz8rBR@jGXmHdUcsamZN2okFjaaVn79OE6scPbfjiKWlkrCTNcz1vBVXhSAB8WwvYFral6cbf/67B4SSx5Xl59Wuxgc7/IdtzFAUPKD8aF30kR1MGAaGHIRqe@GlIP9M/hwsvnaEGk0O8kZ1ImniRp2YOwJXtY2ZjElEXu@PlyPIzmFFJV2uW/pMAjcqYOBGnFSvvUo5J7@xWVW0kySj5e83rA5i0bx2oXGHmxhh2wbCo43AbsDpr2FGrDU76ExKXgdV2yFIJ2uxnoNNdZyJlQab6zcBZ2B9VcR9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNvBFKPsIOQj7Pgg6wzsNRQEv0ao6/YD2e1gA3KfqsNXEVl5K1o/PqVX27ylFX5lR9JVVfUY9CS0jrSXjG8sam7GwiW6rYqhyGTRypzayYaotN0OZhgX@AQSzd0ujgWoJuDt@AJKqlzdFWZXa3@bwWJh65CuXOnmwtSuRqZzG9/OibHHKDGroT6i1IZSQg4AW3Agtlej@QGxBVE2Y06jniz28i2fj30GC4DXtwJWq7rRPnozIt9S4R@yYa8V1KRSTQfmVtG2xHZo8EdOJiKwlBm8PGS84DS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEyuVkn@qopZLwsh0dvVYCRdCHXKm8@vDR47UnT58hytmCbu1sMChUwCpgcBYQDNaoXVpk43u1mlvOySeEoJ6uEtBngcUBHMy6rjzPuH2@8u5VyyUNrJRjWFccRkOK6@1KBplCHIYFzAi0RnGHOdf9sXKEhh1/antf6R/xt/EPyAxn3NEGQnqrH96mnqmcc3E4UGXBzE5x3IfwoOLpFDtv2O/sw9tECFtXYXuq6DU8QIzOhv2L0zObOwratdUhDRgiOPulxgrqZThKHYxZWEEX1RsODev2RdXAO5puAYxyMSVA5xPgNMy038pAW5pidCzTJATPmrixiiNEy3TUZmfmzl5f1Xe3JxFbtMPQMdyCbdlKyh17MoMDGcTqtZp7SNTV3i74KqmWSX7GqzILuBLylfk6fIC70i0EoraoYmQ16w0jdx5ZysyLqWvTtCj1I/CaAbNcup2U5l6raQUIYgSh3k1KhJifnOfYJEtxsjsZ4xS8nKtYNqJvojhmB3O6spynLUo5E0cVWHBuAIh9m1JOGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIScr1XBmTg4zwVa3sTjARtRxQwu0v7G75avtOv3Z@bDtQ1HerP2Edichnm/Gt6zxLVdUY8d0ge0tlm1uYTP1G64oEbOUtMPYFEEI345ERQxTrwH1xo6mvQzqo8zYPk65AuwaaCXc7I7qQQJHL7wHsqAX74krDr6uw98qsnk1LWkSlyp6WMgW1/yBbdFkIa01gSSkvAOI1UkQiaOWlNsXUoYXC3TWvAO9djGM3diZzdMZlpUFFantO0Uie5Znb6TMPLZY1WyxWkE/zuML5tu5vHESdvr6LlrCHLfwxr0/xhv5uzNH/v8L5qj/c7jjoeaOhxXIHuGOxG043@jkMOz9GRxzMuY5uNmOTiPsD3WsVzSi5FsAWOABQ9whpcRyCW27QZwod3bCyuR8BCOh1ce4GPCHGv9IN/5RBTKXH7fD/1cbn/8HN/6xbvzjCuaaGT2vVTvL3fo/psWpSuhmP8zsXqi7ks37oy1d0y1dq2A2ndHN/@ktzf8HtfSJbumTCjwmyIGDuK@fz82iidQOthqN1Nyi4GinXS7i2M/mSg9rr3Y1R4uHTvciPqtCW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OItIbEOTtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStdj@gJSoQ0b2wN9UKFFHJfEtPTpkKqP6bSN5l87oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZS8d4qL56iCZq2vJvLLNPpDV1uH@65X/ImQ4Dz7rW2iEPLr2Kux2zUxiL8EOE69TujFWcwD7QK85MqyiycnIjvRt74RdFm6WauzYYmJenL1IkKM2nP/RWuoc@oYVlRtbRkSbgi5vVlUwzTXLC/lCbZdMs5usW/yHuPSZ5tJnFbWvFwY3kSrQG36aF9N12urjx/PmAClVwA8GYMmn/HNG1f8F)

Latest development version of Vyxal is needed to run the polyglot.
Command line: `vyxal polyglot < /dev/null`.

Vyxal has `#` line comments and nesting `#{ }#` block comments which don't have to be closed at EOF.
Also, `"` [does not delimit strings](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/main/documents/knowledge/elements.md#-pair) in Vyxal, so
Vyxal ends up executing Sphinx code:

```
}#r"\"print(355);400#{
```

Answer (score 5):

## 451. [SerenityOS Shell](https://github.com/SerenityOS/serenity/tree/master/Userland/Shell), 18950 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPJdSD6UTHl/RHJArsBEKg33iBAstnsaY76JZI9MxaARhcKBaCahSp0VYEEmmTHjNahK1my15YlW5YfI8vrvfKVN9Z3Y/d6HCvvRtgbsV82HPvJP4CyHfeG7ZD@ge45mVUFgATYPfJ6w3HjFlBV@Tx58mTmyXPyVR3dH/z0pwm8yBPXnvZtNyCB6Qek61knpieSO1OyrVt@XtU4DkPteP3x0HQCv8IliEKIrTv9sd43Sc@yA9PLEt80Sce03VPwVwnZHDtj3@zWwaYR4pinZN8xrC5AIIF7bDrWK9MDvxwhd037fHgeEMMdDnWn65ORZzkB9c0T8kQHS29sHBO94weebgSW64BXYSGJ4oKtRMhD1/NNgOQapu@7CKu8EESRybs6pDeyzckVyIpCPrBMr0soFiPPZLgoKnn/6N69q64a@bzgOuQeYnjFK0d2xoG7H1yFnyc7fdPRiSqWRfWqZwHoFJh2SS7JV72KUFRmYBlX0ymRnV7PckzyEPJ61bNMDN8XfMOzRgEHRUnuWR4Usx4WJzF0B4oNC3WDmMNRMCUCqwi6bceF7BPdJ2N/rNs0nDMedkwvCugHuhdYTp@cWsGABAPLj@PR0P5IN0yha9rW0ArMLrEtiOT2QigA2umSY3N66npQ9iFM17GnENE0rJ6FUSI8ACBeqWBgMjhDfQoVxwmglhCd@ICGbUbQ0lwCwt81O@M@ccfBaBwQwK1r@XrHBqCdKemaPX1sB1nSAT8oEup@OjCdsFYDOBFAHLkMqxdjipo5q/x6t0tkqNCAx7FJLKAaRatCNA3ciesB1SBUhFEIjFZwlkdzAiUMZdZzKyQvy@C/F7sgtrrtuyEyi6ihpwONlpYZwn3iuX1PHwI1uial6fv7T4hvuB7Y4MawrGHdBMbQA7K5SZJ7j@4mST0uFtHrcHER1cgZFEEi8iQnuj2GGjJfEi6UjxfH5rDIkmvJCkkCWVSZ5HIkB@23RNQ8EEmRy2AARqBqCtwFopZIToH2licaBNZUaNwF8IEGQXIyOJaTWUy/5@l9yzYZ9D5CL2LzgWgqPOUc0aBlaAWNhe67do8FNSgiRaKVSKFIinlShGeZlFXABJPNQaPJw12AGyCWAU0ApGqAtKwyYLN2AfUY6@Iu6elDy56GKdAkDJJXSBGgQn4UgK6WAAq8NQ1vDe4SQlu85mEHAyiNgX4C4AXbOkZ2ZsYcDYtYgpe0sSFR1om8mSXvDzB5IC0QNV8iRUi@ABTJAQpAebUEyYOnlgcUIISWL0DGNLgLLHP@wLTtENTAR1A0B0UZbshNEehTghKDklBlJHQRbrADR1WBdarAJ1VgfSqwK1UFs4bJQjgswgIUfyHHkhno/jEkxNJRu7RQoDsAMAqWArJJBQkHEKAkCZBfQ0RJTsPKA8hDngCXYoFAxSgppJQjpSIBGpdlAmWmAF5YsxTg0ArgoyAwqBsKVA4FcFKgBBQAqmh5ws0VgKKhP8TVIC6QS8lBnByYoTCVAt4QD2qMAkkqkKaqlmcVF3BT85DfvEZrtFqAEi@CH9BNBVxVqGZYjdUS@GPcEtCwhBW@mMwyQuhIBygpbCJQP4EYUDwKhQthwawWwwqt26OB3sH@gMXs9DBqAZtOAckIUWXMHrxzSE1ABUpZxRYC6KtQKzTawuCdi5O3FQDSQPBm16JM3caORYkpVMzSSvpCHwUzsikFitFoGgxiN5W5ucBsLWCYZl83prEntMxs7DlzLWjoqlL@PAMk59DVB27sjn17BiQ25FSalHli2TO3EnXrmnq3Z/mD1zNcczSRjqkHjnU8SyWfz84RVZ/zKKDHglNRmw8bWAJ0cf0BmmZ5UYsYZuTGBbSAsqJQ9Dpmb@z0TaFcmsOP@gRjL4DOaJZmmTl7Vr8PHfsMjpKl2aSd68w5TzG0NQ36/MgRqYtpehZ0@beJMQCRJfYsM/jl8gyGpiKMqd5BSUAAEQ56jjL2dT1rQjq3DdrTzBDUKJ2MgTWKAldWBp4rXJrIpFSYqxuUcq9Kcsyy8WqJL1zLSSVJMs1dcNA/MbF0vneHTvAD7Nmwr8aqC32xSyWNGUtNOVFvmgaiLQoG0FPbKEB1TEPHXhv7MJP2wREcKxAJJAKypemeoMxLO9KFZHza2XY8FHFBMuqankcwLMjFfpZ2y/6445svxyh7zfDqQT9vgjjQ0y07RoD2LXpAhQZ4J31Ib7qIds9zh7QDGmK3a7vuaIWIA538KQK6756aM9RnMoA@GtkgaYG7yQQ9QOZUp8I6leznU2UIQSSMBwUOAGlSIKFYnmlQ2odZh9gayDKLKFaIWr@tIZQ7cyKYBo0FxBMf4zhj266AbGQaRKtLXfNEQhcmpi2KZ4hDJLiB@BWC6OggjSPmFIsY0m1VpCLhUVSyvjtczBrrc/fjrA8sFKbsU30KpdeD7tac6EPQGQgK5tByyRBqDCtBLAlQLjBb@6TrOskghnLqgeALmY5zQoVrpElgDU1QnVyIgiWeo0hjj08x60yhKlNq5USqKzFMrhBK5K4Sijnk5hxYYwERsTs2kGqYtuXQGgQilI96gQeskrlxgUeaTR1uD2TAUageimjAgIeI2pyW4bPWHkrrBoWIcq3p@KC4@CKxUHmDmt93e1DZTi3IOzAsiDqDbVAiIAlip4loiBwlOVag4bFNLGKMRgTcoVOC6nlPLoHY6r6wyCvwtAegdhhjz5uSyQhKwhpCqMBwez2ova/M0QBAkGGXGFMDmicUMq09/sDRR1zXpWzGGC1mdmZbNyGMg@rM7pOfJ30TiA@ibg@VSaz4s2yMRjQjlCC6w8RgRwd6YUaM0ZQSh0vMYvRcV0T3rmv6tMq43nHMADAx3@zTBgKtrTdjSUMU66GuOlQd6QL/CRsZwscEuaWZwaTCuvCu6UADMqBuQtOHQsSS3SE90NPnhFvUUHTDMEdBWFtcytQsZ05TeHwPNQXqKoTARH/ArW@TzSt1B4LG9WdOykXNCVEfhQqMjhw3HAwQqPgRK6uMv9jTa8lDiJMrqfPPMcwCBs/5FTiMaMNAtYmyinGADAV5pGUMkCMGyHOoJA5tzhtfzz64zSfvDYnQi9NGbBRgPpwoxU6Ix2oYAtz2dUDiyEZY9QUHDLrg8AbQuj9cAtmNkbS7866ipIvAGt8EdOg67hKoQMwYLgZZ9KFlQSvjIfIO3Y4rI20u/kIZIduejU9hdwY96WjketAyGOuZ0jEIWmRztStU3VNxj5EWyZ3FDhY6jiR2@wH2hRBhZOtQF7CJYUsFnUsHfgGsjKnWwPlcluIcwrTVU1ghfqe0A2CVCXpUxzFRbdO9KQMC2YNOGhKaEsvzgBmeYFfBeqKoSxFpPYWeQe92kb8iOWi7v5q4iDV6d9yxJlf1dwMdxRc@d6J7pIequweiBzSiVLLnJ9NV6k5jznnxkjsKJBqVPXkISAOJUOSpni9iV3EPGM3h1DFS/EIT47OEHwe9Ep8GA0Zkkhp5DxSGq9ihEoGVZngM7ZraqqQPnbggwFNAN4oJekgieugeSBvQCEHXLJe7HZ2cA/fwiDDZZQpJpJgoYi5Oy3S6cVohIRCX@fyKLAnfM6hBmOvbMAcYnOacdhILBHxLStCIPDhIUtjDogOV@ZgflW6Y49ih430kxQSSNDmLRWDoAFIUGQtEEMuwgnYotNy@HYkva7UaVDaQqYBtdtPzem00FioCp4bAIpVJwkTEwD0MsG2k0pBfDHzBsAHhCWpqrU7OgoEHLY7aLzgIBGTlHKzJEWHDcn5kHY@7VwvaQUcMxGOrA9HJMgK@yoEIwFpD7SaqJheoCrpvEqmKlRfjU9DXKi91xQLlw2Ce6aMQXAtRmSvhFGIQ1tWlJGJRQ7dZhd6dGnYoEjATNHbGjTqA/nE4BBYzomwoE0SN9lpLZUCwOTA45MnO0f1a2BaZp9SxnMqCg@0auk2d1zE4H8V9sH/nYOfg59tLYNhWp3LVQbJypQJ2teOJ0HfGUk5UK@vzMGaA77Zvho0RF8PwXOhNBHcyJypNDehcJhE5Hx98/ipJQBJCctAUwIz3FZGGhQGhi@vo/uBKJ0z6mQwkGUeJwhJhn0QwYwOijv56hM@T8atXWHhXkRqF7oiZPdYZgMhR2neieCJ6XhHAIq9Oj/WINC7IopaD8xsz03zICJ93UXa@igwVqOeqzLuP7@0d1CjYcHRNoEEkPwBZSve6ItR5ewyK@LIwwP7AZJCMOEMcpWqK61ICG8YCgWdlS1bABwCo8YguEexhlDV/ALjvXs0bdRWMuAZQO4VwVa6cl4eMz4roHB7YxRmo@C7rRanHrLOKnZb2WLHvYrdl5PNmMVee77aMWZrdeaB0OgH6gUhu9MDr2BfQRZxJkaFYHaJ/@OAa4j4VIkEVECLMfJuINC3f5lB7ESyS9KVd0NNc2xQ/oByPJ3xakpLRjIJo@FQFnQu/N7GClJxmbyUNYSH1nZ199W4UOBzMpuMZVGlAjRx7Jq@HU4SGD3XEcW2375INiMOkwyhBEJtWZnOn7zrXSkhHR8xqAmcZgf/i8I0@gr7GekXVRxprXmll85W6458Cl1YKGhKJUoiCkmh48YV@ogO5Zvk@3P/iHnQiSl6WY7NMLyDBXBxKLjQZc67UgQiQkBjiszSD8bTktdYeeQhz84KY6ZDRxRF3Zt5LHSnHFKWl4Zei9J57jeIv3OmVqgUurGqBYY5k@4@ePNh/tPdw58NmoObzC/acXC4A4SC9DshC4oDRDVvrBmuamC0El4C24WHzAi4wBgUlmmca@x4wbhGDiAyBFbWGTeim3nMHTtJPX83MKfoKLxyDVaGH2PhY0DAiKNpdG5URj014Y3@O9WcQBCO/IknQygfjjghKq/TCcG29L9F40DHYtqSg6rL/GEc3/GUxABl/arIYbIgLRIcpHUfU7aELygudNkfWQFIMPB27sq3@AHRhnFs3vbQY12CaG6kLGgLoylKcN8qAqQ1oG76jcuJZ1X5HUUusXiuympP4KNhC84ewaz0TVKcU9FZAivQVK2nebt4mU@DSCOkqkAQRN@ggh0@wL7AJCJJ07BT1/Ig4lFvgqCnyCkqjl2Mc0wUuJeXlXFEp5CVQy0BNA5lVwJE3YagHxkAIXAHgCW6PjhvM1cKeb@hOT9wIDRGyIPfdgqxqjWfNptMCAb15m@KGM9aNaauhtNJVcj3KRhg@XYXau5A9rLuRA9RdaoSqSd9kBT/r6tfZWVenratLpGA4CvscYUQe7oAg9coFft0159seRpDmPaWNhbASBn4tLRkQsjEqhw@klAQNCnpaqHoS4iWA0IviIdQc4FtzEchsNCMWmKbBAPiHRlK71JS@LuGisxZyjUVUcGhYHE2B5dFAyLQFDRGKPGiCIwYBUUmCCoQSD/onGQp0IOHIA5Y@gmJiA1q70BGAOufjUGSAXTDO2YzZ2DA2ydCKA547wheJLry6SbiIQgPgyx982gvhxGKbSO7oWOOAClckuzCiSJ4iC4C@fEoCOtLQNVGNx2UTTx0LFRGRo74CdF3J9bYYeGuEh7Quf/Anlx//9uXXP778@FuXH//q5Sd/dPnJv10TXqOOWd/MNJuCmG20CJ@8hvytPfXWzp1bd0oUQ5AnAfn/@xd@9W9/7ZcWcV@S7o8@@tqPPvrFv/mlj//6049@9NGXfvzDr//4h1/58Q@/@lbpOv/tl13jv37shkme4tDIfIJhepDcYAC96H2Q2hobt07PyNraGkRfW9uCkljb2iIZsgVPAZ5r0G9ugW8WnlukAb5rpEUuWhxosD5ZMton0vFz0dSNQRu4pWGmtLQIXd7Z@eScDAaNiQjt/Jg3NvjWBZ1don0BzrgwpHex0A7pyhnE/T3ovplthvyqpBtSsyE3W82zVLObSTcvpKzSAi27beHDT6nphiKKArghb0lJ4lnpQopxm9CQEEg0Bt4MMzphxxbyoC7NKvw9awI9EbBKqEjzY/KUtdDJHRxa/aI5Gky9@QDxeBXIpzj2PFsfgstokP/N85dXLP68KLSgI0cSIwsHYiEOe6GkMZoyvsgxTJvSwvKkqMc6EXpDN9Cl90VQN8S5jia5lpQEAfoQ6sMg0Ww/tHwDVAvdMd2xPz9Gt3ToEFMH16PBGNj37sAacaYxcKGmbwNMEs@SIJFxwkdg00ZRtK4hwo3NGlkGTjFAb0yX7lhQ@LT10lEMhSZ9ottWNx7LzhdGL8U4tSqNQ2RMyOo7rmcKQAiIwdF1SnQZHFePZnP36UjRNV4Z@tIuAPmuZQZZcs92dUpR14G6MFcbcS5kFh/0WYhyYHY52yFCD0QLkZWAZ3alDY7ObbreANgl5AanbNS4jIahh@T6o64YTCAql8IOat6TaUMgpJ2SrqqqBSPfq0R@WBeA2AMoGtTiHFAJIy9BAc90WLR7bBgl0mkfPb67x8YaaOeE3RGOO7WHbncMclioZxyYTj9L9qAWWY47BFbqRPFfHdsHrhswrRgsq0YymJJpDce2TsdIrg5j3BjPcDuuTYdOboo6Cz/2fN3W2aBN5Lvz/kOQjZ8eHdbEylwgST8Z3pg2jtstT5bRc39@po7OUkbTKT6rmPx6nsduLlpoicwl9CihxxCXUoKsGGrR1Bo7hgHPFPkCw65UN@JwCg3HZKRZQmeKSt1Pgl5vwVmjzscC8hJ75pyjzmx55YI65HVmgfIsEK61XAgzD6hAw8RLLleGK9JwbDkHVNaZR4l66HQBpoBD9wu@Zeo7W4GJ0k/IweIJ@4FpRxNwB@bQxUkm6CVtnM0A0R4FWbZG0oS@YoRzCZRN4wwVdAk6RLwqaEETGwksNJdYo82mYzkSThRx6xIJR4irtOGA1s1m9nzGQl3QjOngw2adzQij5uExpUdiY9frbQCxWa9GC9ZWBcOUksk4GIVKcYMYNJt0EvxaVuMlDT4dkuZolCrnSyB0T1RZaE6Ke63zpORTMvQI32xObsnqhyCT4GrE9dtS36zS9UAr6FWNfJKUYYd9OUdDseFdYwDchWQmi6SE8hk7PdfuCmwuCeoaYVoIFlA4oR@vkgwXw5qWFy2QpCtUWVTkqnNrK6/BvVKk9esB5lZjxoBQfCDnx9mTc9I4zpIT0R/ZVgAiEsoTg3BVkXN13Sadz9I9T5/6XLgepEZ2Dt59vyG3GARuqOP8UImV4iRa/gtam@eOccE2mHBVS2AFtNens/YW5heEHIhApxIAfYDBEqiSOKEwR1TyMc9neemZoM@lTCouTYdZYqYvxJ6tB4HpsDrHJulWk5vNpoTJ1GjyW@HQfIXIdP7C6gGW4AcoVsnh0d29gwMRBbpUcg/nOSrQHEF0BGFkVaYjSs5nvkJudZPkFsZJo3LLQVMDdb0dxodKXYVKPzZxNgfZTt/0UuCYxikKA5zprBCNyKSxkEC4NskIKI1iYClQtrcYsMpS/J86x457Gpd4BWp8hlISyJ26XUEpMy2OHeul6EP3QgVNCBLqU9BL1NZTlJOtK@lw8dkQJ1hBqKYCIuSg0SCgM/HrEJgnrVaVzZRDWPADN6Quz9OioKvEa0pU9DVwBkGGQgij116TZw1ZKLcy68tA0YVY4QJvlv85uAhhEbRvLk12PUXb@7WGzHBgM2aMez/16fLHxW0OFbLODDwbmaXBo8VFlOnQtUiLa4oWVyxBI0NWQgcsMCMRS0iEy@/DOkv9KecHrRejUYdUmpzFRFeR5OT8nNKQrKuE0hBMCmGFcRFpxcCYHriQmwfh0vt5mYC21nC5BbbZJsdXYm1elEWZRycmp0snV4RR4YT6Rpo5EwYt59il0yGxqS2LSh4FwDj28Ni@HhNXatLHQlA6mbqAlioW59Hyh50efSyJQ6cDwolm6kAHmkOZF4RFXTqgLzrmfD36lcUVkTPT79niTdq3gpkIL98QUiiXaOBep2OtCgq5x1VT0XspFQ6wBqtiTlRmWby6/oYsEDZcTRq@//tHXSDwdfIPoAvAkbfY0IZOGYtCWEbZhahooY/lJccGiMe2pVMCUNObQBq6B1nS7diwHDSdhBYE6NiHOKQelixUPnyAKLkyGTXEnM2IRe/liSybVHKAGRqrwl5Zj8SSotMfoKh1KRGYeGOZNBJlSqwQzAmbgphTlJFBvRmpaNEQoZWWlftgHIzZE6TZNxaiNcJ7OQkWQsp5vaOYElu/fUORe/rxuOsKo@N@LIEWloSd5Z6ODwnQ0YfToW00Ls8@yyBbDx29VwWbdVrSKX29qVb4ztgfCR2qVXeZjTaE4Q0peDZ7rgpihfvfYsNqqlk2fbxlTQyhQ0UJVwNIuOJSmCOadYXMtt6ZonQx@Oy1LJ5ZB45TMzIZWVsxtToarY6PmiSNXy4vjz0RDUaPZTq/xFZ1hioVzXC4zvMNpQr9kTXUbUHtzhlXMu1lE/PXgsZzejQObkGg@xBurOTY8RhjW/dmphuq@LVh5GsD0lHnaBkudPAjohRFRZ0xx2gR2AwkLp@lj7mJfmsZwaLtE0JsWt7YXSPAxZEras9bsC62KBGXfs5VB9FdRRPDPcV7lbc/APWSPZf3Xa@WYvUWbEiwDVuHnnkl418Y1sNhwzdUyVPLN@ljOWGPlyIaGPZS98XKHg3YzQ/AvakC@5bt@uSQPm8iUN8DKrDn8qo7T0tLdwQ6eD1vvoHbRLP5swLV7b5rF0p9SYfHylIfez3k8OH7bXlZzIsU5Q28KBJ0XEcJ3ys5@LHkHb@pgOimPQ9Xcs4Zb@hMlzGkcLZide5AuMedCstzdk8u0ZiixAb1ViSM61dO9Wn0/hk6iVWkjTqJ0ZQKyCDHYYRyCQyBx4TmnyW13M2pdd@OKV0DW3xTJuYK99g2oVuiz2tFSlRZ@YwxFFl@exbVs8fm2FyqOjzuvDDDDuPtE5dDdNfDsXQcvsctF3GoV6Ey91bYYc@LthuZho7TdW8WThaZ1wjk6RGquU/A8AQN12P0nfFoofQW9CrngJFmMIqaqNtdwAJ9PitfKb1BxlmQrH2T3jfqOkw3w6VNtbwsy6HoMTf3sWC5SQfS4rgvLPZcSJi6zFKehcX5Lm/OuDwNSpb5xXMrWYq6SvWmgctlybEcM5ji8y25Y8d17c9SUsAkccOrC3qmQBeJ3lRi18SXcPsDmQ0u@Dgk0emtGlZgvUeoFQJ9UN29qdDnJ2feqjQFnH4c4tTQonXVyMpTx9aHna5OUp1TN30dKO7FxNEZtkrUvmmQhg5PKGJJLM5Kp@t2TFtnr0khd1O8sqgtadvhrCfOkrK50dlMduIK7xhNIa9WF9SDgTk0qfUG8Vrv4qkO4WtloImL9yrviWka0mTPNFYFGFnQrB18LkzGzskugeuAYhPgAjNUEGxcwhi6ribWQ92z3Ac7j96dn1UPA@wP9b55L9IO5oYEcIUMU5xmxuWDAxVyB5uSAdFCsKFg6RybUz96L434cGpAQY2HKxudgcOCb9HKVi16vN6FOQN34AzMAVtpHNtW1VKoSAEFHNYepz/ARU6j0cLi53k62K5tz9MBWQxjOK7bW5rGHm6CxL07S@OzndXh643DVHrAGh8aVlbTgTkGPu67gTsyBWpbFdTGIQ32XMVzojnan3Ws5EaNFkgRvX9W@G/Urfq6G4xG9NUe2WOfPmhUge5RfZM80WOLKujyN9fri6/cYUcMHcVwxQWdxl3epjtWYAxwkzCrkWbf7RgD601IhwcTSNHgBrO@le6GlLGIcBedQaEH8npTEetLbd7/EF/7qwo9HCdhnUFsuKF/XzYWRbfhCiP92PDZuB@aSAWHPudaF9usW6HbnSsvx1YwAzq3CiceyGQD7WhYhXu4eGClJEJXw8/YYbioYGUtpcIrCqqCKYOAoKxKdnFd1lwT0zT2WMobDNc47kXseSUlwwUpdIjLmht8BPeFqrOwkmapZO0Mxn3/Om9jY85dkFbwsVojpwtS58ZdoVvQnfC1ioKqLeFONXi3QfwYmzdODORvnBmg4RRb0F0LXm14QamMVw4P2dbIZ08i9NRVwcIFNqBmXp3VYrSZLtcTw4Lpmj02jo@mN8lkoF@D8NqH/lwwcKIXh4GRT7NOm/Ekx@0DvxZsMgschV2lKy1dALO8@OPuTfjwkdnXcTXsAyvAdYNLagVtH8sWzrwR9hfGum99YQw5W1XZcPM9mzPz5pdNom0JvId63zLuLxREjGRI4HDRIXstVH90ul4WpwPLxwU3seGGMRescqwSY61rgwi9JOTVwef43IFZA2J72ZaGXjZA7I6muOVnSk03jQ1bAR1ADN@rtKhVy5tuROJ0PByN/fC1HAe6pGd@gHXI2Jl/agFw4SVwTTLQ7WD5IOzcaCIIUmF/NzMuT7JCvmjZbp98sSQTkLsCYqGcu6Ti3IGe9wmuF/GcJTWRpv2Wc3eo8wtMbvNfQtmauDLdsYKbBzCCANeORG/MDOsU3FOQBx7gU9z@rBCEo@UUeTDXycX7SN/QRUMNO3THnmGiMT4cYl4iD6Gbu9HSVwu30@PhFqfzmo3h2tCMwGAvbRqG64wDwRs7N3L/wo3cv4IHBM0VN0l9Ye/h0/R8qdMFwm8SJKMjpGamlbPbVyqT5YAstZpfLoaOxP677GibA7pO9Q1xdvD8HYOy5bvuMhXkyRQ6imXMfDy8axo4l/XGNB65D13Hhd5lBIxveGCyjdgLqwyWR8RoD3CrMdCh@8ZkDinYFZ0Kkx70kdmBcrRnprfpWxjgu3qgr@ha6LAXVcli0xvrhGV3TO8FHc@aM6/SGhcRum9OqBqwumKwtiYEhsGkVxxqWmgLC5ML/sh1Hfak3FOGl/LwZi4BrJ0@3n72VsTV3guq91JVajGrj0/Y0gWzy04KWJVXz@y4NnvesCDGsdhEte5Zpi89wI3n1K2QIwJIU/6NvKJ4I6@YaTEgmZ7oPp05Xq4VzEAqk8@wLmWge4aLkzah4YYlI3O7xd/AjuMF5Gw2uwOEnwBn0o1xeLbjm9Cyh50hfaxUAOZK88CEZLq4Uu1w6gT65HphssGXcH/53DKjeFd2xJawURdI6gloF@nlCtwV6lkj@qCcd@UMLl0pIjiWabzScaDJpXSZDa8u@EPepEfUuGK4da650IFQSafbjJe2mMV1UyCI2KYQDDxQw6XgphHa6IyLJUP646GJ856LEwkrRU7XH9DMusuneGMm6plCeNwa8Iz46DUm1wk7KyVGBA//x3fek6BTbRdy0bkPwKLePKkMyI89J3y9TU174vpBz5o8BrxxcfkqtoHZykMUeLEWgKaNVZmA0nPGNhsQ6M8t@hl2qRol0MNzBcGmbDkwBdM5EegpXJPrOXLZviFpBw9VDcyuEG5Cx8Fy4UG0hSgOFr6XzOnN80BcUahIjLCTQi5cY7iMuKcRBwD5yQ2EkU/f0sh/sv/g8ZE48pWl/dDOABfdX5PLFna1qyV5bpTohe7NTc2xtVBdyw@kO4eKsPtgX8QAK@jNRu8FeOHk0sJr5VBkdJCmpK/UXtDXDJYLfPePHj7IzHbckdTuwHOHZnree/fwMIsbGN47XOo9H/setI6eO1kZfX9PUdJLqm@4LXMVl1yS0ipIRyZokVAZ77NDMd4oRBnuyOweTUfm@9BJIqf23zL5wspMPtJPrD62QlJeSSjaUElZLOTSc@t@QUk2vfi9qjyPrRFyS4O@JPZauUICJQRN8rTlUsJNk9NXpRUih5Pjny2SIl@vrfNHuUq6/49FTFGUVXQ@1HtQriS/srAWAyyb4rTdk7eYDTVDZUSInYQAapVgvXGxclEYAuuW8IEj5qEjGDsrV2bcBCB2Lixt8KemM9UdAaWl0GXkxlLGF825uZp4scgJnvO8dNoqXm9NUgY1RmQ@8ua8dnfv7EceB8w9tL376Cl5ovug8SyBaM5BnEkWLwQcr8Hju1YNXOx3PeDUrJ/oj5bX@wo51L2u60wnc00FZ3Gxq6MnVsZx0EYDmbY1sZbxboONzzxZvhIkSoOtkHenC3Le/IkYYYTLL/@qosgyPe8E34rMrFcqMEmhSZ/iYVnzXkf7cdU3sF8WwSG9VKt6YE5wxQAbpVymnC7l34UbeHsxvZpd3uRXusEvd0N61/zQETdTKDcAzN/gR/Ji7P3AtU8Hrrire@YN5LgJ9fINqJfn@E14BDOdvQrNq4VWXAkevpbWtyMz8HKjgduxcgsi8uLOyZXD7YHu0fUHfTdcPM/sy5M6HUcN@aH@ypxvwsczPmAOxrhkfMlEWgcEMdPpW@zENXLHDfao7QZtId4Yunyu2RrdHY@usBI8nP4Kd/oAlDL31Cd3cKvPTD5colzi2qLl7quEKRKPMOHhgvePdqJEHx9K6lyKMyw@fLLgjJvhgseHc26eOZms0raEySrlZanPLNVHR7mFZDfrz07esK8CejZgdfF7ZZfL@M57h9dbJ2oKg2BoRz7v6Y4Zwem6Ad0dFY/DTUazwdEPBrQCRHxsyYIu6EUsC2D4UruNp5W026tqyZH5IR1Yhr6SBOYExXom4IeHApmT3CAIv9dBo6xsAO5xzLUPRwPLmYSW4cwd17qR1As/yvEOObTdUxIpPHPNJ@yxIIp@Yjo3b2oSytrNHbI23@su0Imd@h@@VpHozore@47pecvCHBjSvcjyvppeEuK9wyjAMt9d28VB0q41Hi7zplEzmWVe3kLDvhrJWuaBh9YfD1zPWeYZFUylcsdcCXrtBr/hFLS1ZR6dXm@Z857vLnN@OLYDC4W0yPORO4bWE1WrPS@S3uqb9WZTrIgzK57B6w@89LwLcIqhO/ZBvLPs9NWgwgsrWHC8Qm/qhocAm47ouFfhvueSz1szPOcz8Wolld67N/NZHCce40wh3R03M67aKTWaam@svq@sPrUsr3iONbziOztfad9zHWZLz8/7RKcrLYF2X7et9OqJUPUNM6HI5pg/OdGWtTJg@PfmKfr@dBJLzk9sulc3tO2qkIG@YaTDb0T4dPWlos0NCrAlIyuWvc1Y9hf2hroxP@S4cMhCNG3kz5j4nGbhHT66s3P0wZMHof3z@rATpRCdi67eZau24jUaV4ZR6Mnx0iE@BX@gQ99FR1AE3DZ9ZQbtg50HTyJ2PACRHEiJh7vNDTTFfJekup6vD8uxBPkw2qd0F9oemmec6P7UdIVxnCnW3y1T81fuHrh6ONTNoeeOdLpWGo/M4HDs9dIrN7Kqy5Wdwwer2Op7UTYP33343hfuzbY5PbKGRBZV@F9pGaIiyled1OtO2nWn3HWn/HWngihfkflWSINi6abNy5pYvg5buYa7eh1R9Tqi6nVE1RjROSf5utOSFJdQS5GXuF0Lp8yhQVematdTVK5jr1zPoyIuAa7M7/YO2bLwgr7ZvM2qzThQe0zPdKxgCoLrIX7XCp3ZpniQgOY/O@Bnw@Ov2CESbOu@L0bfhkilHOh40ouf6Jo/hwAP506t4@G06/TMAQh7fk7Wwn3@4MFHJweEJxvgGZaWMzbxaAL2kZ6gtg7J1GpKvnx@Du9cXiZb@B2sClFkmjZ@PLBMjwzMEvR9j2acixBokPWzcCd/paJckLUa4Ss8Cc9SiE8DZydaQ2J4Fi9klAjHClkPwGc9OgeA0E@0kHNCx5kFA488BZsozZ@IUg1PSgD81s@e7D/ZOzzaOXp62JBbF@FJClHOHAdSi85ruaV1eSBISEsoNna@PT3Bw4bk6Hc5cHzaj/JF8JNUi1mrLWRtlil@C@OsnzmOJNHDJCThAvATeJYa9UUBG5wY7CjHtNDCc0Qq7FwHejwFlBsDzdM0oSArRF6W8Ej3fchW6H/1q27UF78KWMHvAmLC4ZHkIM/3Xbcbpuib5M1XlOK9nf0HTw/2SITgrCadWt1gUCvn2Yn14WF1PB4tYdNTV5JhlCSUVa2WvJcEwiTFJKnQ4z/oafF4sF0yrg94cEgYe4Ok1il8oGAyLhTpv38kXSRF3JSShrDJCKkkJAvtgFYUPNrvCCoJuXuw//7eAUH89@5SZyQRgiBHeELBX3y/y763Ep0IFn0R0RuG@iuUlu9a3QoeCGKYJJFT1PBUoS7B0/DYmRnEnNBvl9CaRwfP5r6RmKanNHHzp5hER3vMTh/BkqNcYT4m@y4KPdUj/iBL/F0pjqOnDkJ9P6WHZl45TzJNz2xj339kJ73GoGnVi77tgJPLoG9TmcvyLTxTBMuh5469K40Et/vT41NFsoMfi8RPUur000GA7NgJ2PFz4ZFUCaihYsy/smSdIss@NMTPBUxurkEj6Zh9yyG@Y4GIHVTIC6jBOLFbYWfOCEI9eS1KBLpCTQIq1XMB2QDAEA/wJ8JoD88RbHrS5a/8ktSvEjAHYP5qaJ7Id8D2tdDWA/PXmfmZhBVUSl77vkyMyzxCeL5smAOGCNezfvpT/H4sn1pXlOO2d5JJ5uUqPJRqnuTJrfWmIKw35Nr2ug6EDF5OmtCcpY3ciXl30Ovu96Umz4McnpOkjbOzs@S9jSfWszwpCF1LLbycTC@0gvZycqEppZfHI6XQEF9OWnyplj1uNRst8uTJh6/br9P85IQOv6aggu0@5pUcn6iUydlWQUscl/HbcpDDY/IKruMewT81v@rOmXU0d3pQb5M8STSb@LFXvsgD20u24E85xXO4GM9o1MW6uNV6/Trd0PVgMiWWZY38bhdud0BSqpo@JNDUbkMjYhEk0qRvSkS48sNJj0x2zH5/vKdPrfG9YFssiiVRnWNMmw@/@EF4VT94@pSQp@Tp01cHK9hYK5NJCUKDmieR4wMQjbMTUmnr@QR@He4vPl27yJ49aW/@xcdDyVzD12N8ffXiIZoPlfyttbVbd@7kcllVVZn5yRef/PzOzk7ubjb/pJHfygny2uaf/9namqpuqtJay/eVVrJxfPwhr8o5XvyL7yXbT558wffr2n/96HVdwUcRHiekSMp4aUQBIz5LcCsknydveyVeJRS4ElP6ayci97M1otS3iv/jm49fJoJEXZU@8OAdJF4mCqUEM4IBbFpkO0nUE5sYrHCRmEq1Wg2Mxf/x7yB@/T2Agz7TTXjU8xGswjRRF2o0ynmiXgCDoqqQ7v/z0UdzGAI/A1ZSgxYplCK3bWCIjQafK6r8VguuDXptcngUkyBLUhTOCQaB6RKldFu5jRYLLPBy4IXjZ80Efh/z8TYRnx1koE/IiO/X16S7mwJc4khSFLWpKLeB/Qq3Nmo1AfoV2mw1LX8bj8lM096w7wYuMW9/sHAlPvifci0FU/3gn@Y6ILuWYXpulksU1raf363XIedaXduoZ@gVNjfa8ool3nW3gescDcae5eInN6sP8OMxdV4uqXw2m90@aEMUMpkgMYXJRGwjCMI@6J1gl9gmzAUbdujIaiVcdeQJLRK7s1iRdRaOPE82oLW0nq8Ol9jD6y//w19@@y@/SX/fpvd/whOtnK7VkzYg0Ak0nDpc25WKUa/zdY8/a6K9DrVNrpQqJal90UxtNOqtAxB23z1P5rUkObSn2baKVzPdbND4dZpsPUwe7fXEzLnOXOrzbqEHC0wd4B1SiiSifM7lK6YaIVfCcYloMZbQOKm3BBzPrQkNpZBvCSxWYxsKh1eLZb7dSgjrU8S9VVfz6mOyXWcXGaz7xEVsNLUQZSTEtz7L28xnZqvPOyXqUbT6LMxnDRfiVIac@VIoe9YjRLfXKmulSqGiSu366qs6i4EXDWqa5hM/cZKIryoJ62FEz0RcM@fcns2XRFwsJKrAZCHuG8JxiUat0TJb0EYW/p1OaGCsDotLKyh8NTSpbZ5UoX6omqD227ysQGvbbkfsfAuuNfjRP1yxFZ9r1CV0pkGuX2ukomyompS/VdhTsQ@@ehFPaNQzlEcKrXpGRF4piFcCcdCrEKPT6bwyOiCj6HpHN3Ql0Mf6RJ/qQWfcmXQCY2zgl5TJExT02mGmPc3NuyU3IoYoJLS8sp64jTVcU8v4UWLQUkolraxqRUUrFrSirJbyWqmsFXNasQgAtaKqlcs5VdUKRa1Q0goFrVDGDz9DmAKE0RBCMa@VNS7xurFGDhh/m5BMdDUzb7yeipSj4UUNLt6C4E4SIEKNjeMsl/gnuOqKqpAN6CZleIBsSI1EpT/I4a5ujf0sRxIg9p21Xm80Xm@Q@dISQpzhJba3Wxnh4qIB5mo1/G/WY2OVXswEWW1dZDKbz@ogDT2rNzIA8lkIUhQIBSq266S1Sb3i1MLkQv/NVqsPvpmR38cqI1AkXgISmc3GZs3dpbdIW6fQglQ2FzDf3qZVbRti1dehW0hnMuuCsNYA0I2wg4LAWCHDLAIkCJYCUebs7Ge8yeYmMJmLzYv6RWPz4mJzE/6b9HnB3smcmyy422AE32t/@ppdK8LM/FvIp5oNqd6UmiGvaoFdlOroIkpNMNThDeEamlpqYe@IcpDY@uf5F7OzZ@yCKLdEwJpLbJCNBJ4FpSU2uMTzy0/@D7ybl5/8AGVaAj@zwiXOCOES0kaZUDf6KoNg99AhD9nlgBnvyIou6FB/iI4OezioKUvSc5FUBKoup5RSIS1i9992e23cbCuS5xAUgu31TWhEEe8lvFoq8O2MMlVJYpMvFCm7/blrVzKZ/BfP1XIxybRx3C363Pf9h3NYzvCEwFVVVgTlvM4O9WWnrv/csutf/Nyqi0uclwnSKEUYXbgEVKOEJIEWySXqm0NcuohfLBHw03MntQ@FpzvCrjsc6QFV13F8D0SF2v5erVyuoxplrj@hjWfj7gY8FfjvrUEmSLMHQZu9mjEEEb3Z0/JqE7XWd3XQ3oHRCZ2X@HvwCn/kyMDfwUv8kaNX@DsI8EcedvB39BJ/Ox38HQ3xd@cl/h6@wt/TPv6an9M0pcqv6yfdSRf@k1frk/UzSquMUlYu1ic8o1liq978HJBzlKyS7eTnGnRUKF9uNdC3BR6fC7xpRa@BlFPt1MrVUU2tDmtCTs1VX9VUQa2Gn@lw/aw/9bO47tQ0sDxMI8WrWyqfrrICTWm5cvpzbLim0q7ZOPaS6lpeyvWBF6EBj6AlUXDwTP7kGx9/nKzVkkKSHlSfU1zvtRCmIFr@7EOKbAtzRSVpDKiV864n6MTy4QEOGa0MMYUOOnSoQy4PmIMTfkobHuDUKGcVNVvM5rJKKatkIX9yVilmFTlbAq1TUrNqNp8tZIfZV1ktq8C/1Wi0nzVUsL2Cnwp3Lvuq1QDum79dbLUar1q3lHIrk1MBF8Aol/4ckIeIJvusFpKRS9TIurKuyLZsyEpH6YDBIrJH5IE8ULoK1URlk8hTeUrkoat0wWTCTwaTJfeI3CeyIzsQDHzBFLTlAE09ePXh1wNAHvwsXM7VUWSDQEI2aqv0e1ZKG2PK5LxN3h24fpAdNbkGSRL@ufn8@XMckRcLVgs/b9Dgnz9vShsttVwiIjZMsd143ky2@CaPh9@q5RzpTM215nMexCuZZwWILiTh@41kq5qQmk0pLFioOEiEi4t2e@/R3XZbwn6@Scx6ZjsDndT2dg06rfC1lahXt5oV2g1GXWFC2txq1jUBzYUM9GgquJH7JlSorJT5jNcMMLzra5QAreenz0GbS52iTnd6Aq/TyPBBEx5tpu1Rb@n0g@aclRrgwrCS9MESCAsGwNrxprHkBn9Qjv@p/tY/r//DpySdarTSqbOLzRS90vhLp88uzi7CZz2dSoWW1Cb80AHsGOXsoo5GGugMTI1UupW@uGBu8EylNxlAiLJZp1Fnwc5Q0KdJgniTDhNmj9T/nDeJs5MKr2Z4TP5zfnPTM86bVcpoc3KZJPjn4KXPpk@azYkMLKITnc0tOGRdP6djzemqgR@@W@80lNaff4@ev76VpoHyuWpV2SDMoubUajUX2YqlarUUWdZTqfL1qy5vKQVQA3O5dLpaBctWBFYGK8RtkNcZUiNNeLZu32aJlNTz8wimlitkZJzCqlajlPKQrOnrBm3uoB2e7T@mZ5cDv8gnCLIF@sla2jfI9OsHJ7qdSq63a5XJ7dup8Au3Wzvp27fVsnx@rsilTKOEnFjOaloxK5TzrUZlIkIvPXC7Pp2YuFVoJUna9VKP8GukADQlKOSWWqfwy8CJ1VwRvAkwixQmR1I89jxpPp3e1DBMLgehUtAb5IHxy/RXpE8VewVQmFrpBkbGr3Wl2u3O2LID6JHa7XT6lqIBv9fKQIN47C3JJ6t84gyEtFLR6pG19TZjfnwVfcj/gitBgNOQs4sErV0kl0@ngDOnQT6/SODPQyZOBTotn09Xc7KcOLvgWWClXGah0yRXSJUy5fBXW0uTOgif7IcStJbJbRQ3tnEo0Z@suJDPV8/MmnJROzMr@DWei6oRfpUS93ubt29rZSjmkpwgd8d46kS2yYWdRA0EEZRj4dHkkskMuXWbw83wXrJS3aa1TSnlSSJZZY5CEjobUipnFEndyCslJDpn9fAUBxDGOIVSZo2scSp944MrM3qtoWPiyojCjX8u0YWLdEmH9PEifdT6iUVsehGbMH/6NIw4kMuu0De20rh0nCByMeOryaY9tLxGqxGz5fIKa2JJ8mBsWDj8@OTBzu7eUVbdFEhCvbezm1UPn95JKGjNz@zUW0P7wd7O3cdPIcKTB3s7h3vv7r@/9/QJuPvkdHbFnVzU1cVd3pxpif2UfMC98F7ppqmbY9Nsn47Hpy/JC8tqW1AH7DFk1e17xDfbkMORPsttFW7D8vUXL3RvRC9y@d0vX373Fy5/7xuXv/fly9/79k8@@faX4f4@3N9g72/8UTmPz5988qt/cPm7vweO/wnuP4X705988psfsZvafwj3f5lz@2F4z4VjNwewvvaTT775vZ988vXvwP074f2d6/evfLr8/vaXVt8Y75t/cHOYb/w7uP@QwYrCfuN3mRu@r4X/XRbu69@5/PV/z/5/Hv7Q@HuXv/5DfISWX/7On/@Xy4//o6qW/vzfXH7pm5df@vjyS1@9/NK/VC9/898o8vzjDy6//cd//Sd/@Nd/8q/o//v0@Ydv87/8zi//1f/5V//XX/1JeH8K978H06d/9R@hXf/dH38X/9/847/70@/i/3///b/742/93df@NTX8FjP8w@/8EXv@6OMv/@hLv/ajjz9Z8fzyjc9P3sL9k38Cl7fH823gvE2@PqvLJz8TPv8YasxSgToANfcXL3/zK1B5fx06rcsvfx93o8C94v99VaFhvs9s/x8wqNfzjD4ymOD@1uWXv0E@RCr9b0Al@JMPP4Tu6sOwm//www9DCn4V/cD9Q@rIrsWIzDPynfl8lczCQTH8NiGN589bOMG8AJpafvLJr32P2hJmpU4nD1EMKKmlzAbocRvlcjyruInhvxKD/Nzsl1iElC9pjuNUQwy@ilxsIbGvIv@7/O5Hl9/7l5ff/a3L734NBQIhV87uZAXlDUIQBMy/RTgMWHibcBgQkm9n6OiqkAGzeS7hdqntc0KqkA@tpDVnwU2p19uowI/Ao1LZOMsKW01SYDm@oHFxvxXIuIqg3spsrUlE0bPahqZDQCnHwpGKsy3nMsUNXZe49rmEe7PIOZkzSgoLKakhLZkXruuSQsiSosZe6xGAOBtcIoPoZqiItBEJbnmNTDJhTibhRD66Q6DJBjVOCJtvmVDvCTeh8/3Rf2accCRDhSZ64fe3IiM1hPGitQJFuMOM5CGtzCReQ0DFScIkuQ3mQpdB0MRzoFPRmdPMpFZHA85MgNcd0GBqtQxGrDGkwMrwq5cIxSeTqUHmMTaLk22XEMTkDoUCMWuUDrUJi5hBePWIJhkOnSg2mVLtLiRYm9xFhwwCp2CfP6/VS7VJHcG9ZkTJTDJ3KE4IrJaZ1F@DvUZhQjwucfc1oFKqZTL1EiaImWRllG2zksrTzNG84xw8Kwh440K4rW1CbvFKiWfzW2tIMBYan5lZaAyIUQ6e84rKP@dzqsxD4GZmI8wb/UdGem9Q6q/RdMMkWd4x5TUKjLSfbzwPA9KQkJogiKJI4MZFJ1tkm2xxjGqZDEUGXpmQiLSy0MoROxBKKS5DS52RDeCDM/1KKVHVXBUUlipBJ8/g8KNmdCWTzK1PcJXaGQklaDn8UucFp0OYnKxxZ@d6uIptXScX4FTgqJCNadY2PvOFyCLV1tfXuUSd1/jHdLY@I0nEO67QtYjQ9qjqVSF8ocyjs0kXZjIqPsRNGFmOmquYTXL50fcSObmY4NaT9KvIhCVEbmXYvb29QW4BWel7zm1Cl/wJGc3NuQlGxs1Mhlch0boLtg1KwgyFxj0jiRr@wT1Bqxv0xk90z/KzXJYyviy8xFoCvcnjx49DfKnDsxqXgXaoagracaZ2PB5DdLOLqyKyWVHMitls@BbpmzqIoUGkvuFbXEfSk3kVUSmW8HOojjFAunCvX7@GusEhLSr7OGZMjaSm5krUk9BqMMHFePowy7HDImx7Gq0DVnNljg26EKWQIyRFawQOQhNc3JqCOp7m2Ao5Vr2iK5VUS6UkDQklJqYgGANTUJBTsZXFdFsYyRcXrIDZvBUHU9mkAy7XiJfvMvxSpXw68tx9THYfP3y49@ho1Kq1oLeh39812yPPNUzfT6HnzqO7rP6q5UIa58Yx90cVFXknt1eRsSJn9u8e7B9WCKNZWHgpmpMqXesQUqascInR6IPNhIdTH57J49enXP4Qn5UZMVJqWYOoiTqXMExU0KCm4h/uKjkw@1iBH/r9O@6EpOQsz2eVAurZaVyMAOj8vDsmeLokO9IC@AOutRQhx4h5/UyYm/xDhzo5UDlmEBRqIFq5FBmKzKAUCxjgMfswm8bVD/eOAPLRY6KoskgO3I4FSNU/JBOREOACB@7QdLPCBY2NPOnIGroYwsY5in4wWMeP3fJNmZ8j0HqDjQ2pmgZPJVfIKvlia23NPhMQTpNWmjNcSXoB1jMBafIOXIR7hyPvgBNcwgXh3JHpkHAGZf9xlVVf3CxNUoD9YeDxSh44Q5rD6aIQHjeav6pIdWhqixOvXGLti18MSL2@9@iusH@PSwAXHZBoHapgdcWBSKtOd@yZ1LdPSNd638KNHGLX8ke2PoV2DATbqANFApwVT1xcXPQA5v49otZVamVxu/i8MKhLB8wXE50jwKN7XOJ2NILDFW9XKrXXSq4IuFUqrzVV5cCB25C4hNVbg@pGVxJtSOzHO7WcImcUNmmQckia5/mqD0hpWkna4BIKz8NL0zSOtiHCVUyO0JVmr@VaTQjZfE6hC804PHNfn9TU@ArDTm7NwmoyC4s@4EH6gUfkyK94ezbgomlRzwBZwaXX9LOr1ZCpyLdvaziOpeXkOO@EkoZcQJmuazmNFtI90wmwnhH0bSVyxXAqE/LZSnC2GZBuDcyJJmacpsuWso8sPChkDCELOWCKpxVVoavKKzk1l@AJhkZWqZVkLtFIAA/gGi3gBf/Lf60G15r88/0DWRqNGjcBXjp/h84Yhr7Di@Meuo9n/8ePh/PWG//Dx@7Dx@7QhT/0lg@RyVdn/2p1wXrzP@StyF6rVUA1MCdQ3@CXk/Ng/Ydvf/T3v/4f/v43viriFdpih3/49reY@@/8Kj6/9e2//9Yv/P23foO6/Mrf/86/Cr3@4Xd@n9wFJjB9pWPdvPz6x5ef/NHlDz69/Pi3L3/wJ2id/3/yb0Ovj781cwQzulz5f4v8za/857/97a/@9acf/e23Pv3b3/rjH330dbWk/OijX/rb3/r0r//0awTsP/7hV3700df@5pc@/tFHvwjh5v8//uFXI68vxY5gBpfrf3AHuNz/f914IYPGtSF0ucNmeAhpne5caCjlXGsPeFyDtDaj80nrEHqT7b8keMBMjccKKAUWc@Prvmn3RNwPUOM3R3VNVvnN8JDzOnnfdLAPCePXu7Wua9BPlFe7ooWfisedhixeLsdXXQePIqzFU/wklT7r107pCQJVs9YX8dAbz9FtiN5xu1PRD6YgJBqu7Xq1JKi8SZCz37dcm9ZiMO90XQdlWKdmgpqFsw9bmparQP7EkTvaUvNFgQgNRQbBE2@llO1CP@htQf9bUbNr5laxWOmKhm3q3la@kkdvI14JspWXK33xw4cP7gfB6AAkJtMPtnJliIAHx@ERT1ulSj4PLIXnMw2aYgu/vcwEDGFtDfpjU@8K8MaFIr6glloVmn6tlkxuaYoqKBVNLnFhZmcEc6qOkFMKW3IlmCcj2bMtx/WyPIefiI1LAQtwoNRzcm5TgjeBssdVKyBO1cmO2TexP6Ilp2xKI6wTYISgOhg7YMxvSh0wWmAsb0oWGMd1TZE3pTEYjXpOAVeD1RIsDWJ1a5Am5iyDaGexumQHylkoX1Qc1zEvuEpWz1pntOQqvV7vYuMsM7OQxDZdqa5eWal@BnrbmcDCQWlfCHq2cxZbq8IMAlch46xgzTzBRe9B5TkLl@9UeDVf4quN6sxeLPDV1gW3PTS7lo4f/m7KZ9djFUAkZFATkFCTcBcVz3WDSsfsuZ45C6gphSggQ@h6gBx/ESfXlDHFs@vJFeYCTc5mdI3p2bFd4zhMiX4Pc1lauTx/wRkhOTyze8ESylaykSOLSqsNFiMWaOLZMy6xcfC@Vq9DvT3LFdVcPpdXtUIhX1RB/C3nCvkSVBu5IOdVFZhHrlwqFy@g1UrS6wT9oB7ZPYtac4V@UiGlV9hBo40WSb9@ZNlnJU1g7CeVroK4lHjNJW4dvK/W66vH4VKgSryvCvWali@DSUOTqlGhSlUFVRM0RVA0/L/BoOL/7cOr8FfxCbE0lTvCY5gegRQPCoxDHuBJMoFLjlyX7km7YxorQuwOdHrk067n@v4/Iswd3TlmXnctduZv7HVfxw/P@UMrGKwI8XQ0tBwfN7b9U0HYG3YAQeT2LMAdeHi26y4LUCRPn8DjYP/d@0fxe3muH8an6ANx2DH6EONob2f3Plcgdx4/unvllQ/B5cmDvXtHsbXIfKOo@RjEz@89eHDVGr5yj58e9Mauhzd37/HT3OwRO@FWPi4H12Kg2JkCCR9oRREPVRWyRvLFyKBwuIvwdq5MbofGfGFmlNH4AdunaPnxRkO21bXCHUWbF3WCXUDHJPihLrNLh2jpoZLhyIZSLHPciDjuKSnKpOvatu4Rt9dbA8eB7pOOaaKabttYEzHpU9ezu6dW11wD0RjSKCv41XFEgrsPQIZjY4AJgJaERxF38Rv1uCSjY49NMh6RlY7wQic0elZ/AJLGqRsF4Dq6TuD@rBfEN@ev4GaHgKVB3a752NeDcwlu5zEOwCR4fpfn7@uBLhWfERSfBhU@yPN9nOC2/aDbUPkc31rbypWAy@/KOOxuEXWqS4pUBRoqBXdb2Wib/Vq@oGxhR1yTM9uJUqnK8yNf050scMdsBUdQvJpjPSNG1akQUtwgpGme27maIpNK5RD4BdkFntHRyX0TmwpwY7rLm1awyt/89vd//GffuvzKp5c/@A2UAcld1zN0XPWOyjihqnWok4t0LEgtl/KlsqaWsqVyKZdXCvk8LpZUiqViWc4qslJSCqV8WcmWcmUQ3nK4lDJfLoYavSRtkB0bB/GyTGuXNioA3jHwW9ybdFhJHNS5BFvvQ16l9DRJ6LF9THgT4vBkx@mbNsDA8cCAbp7dsGrQdRPItFYkAFknBkncu7cr37vH83fQgsscd2We76IlX5Ll4h2eN6nPbgnlU95lcUp4wCQfMIss34FiHDMA@E0Fnh@gZa@AkzQ8b6Fld@fePUynhxYV40OwY@bDLHZkKUIwBy2axgC8jKFBsB2WTo4iuocWTBJ97jGfXfDj@XcjdNDngAVjAO5HOd3Z4fl9ZtnZQZ9dmu08Q/TzaNmhF897YIEmxvN9MPQ9aNw83wEjNjSeN8BkTHVww@@f43H8TqDz/JSRBwnE8xMaWjeOeb4duWMy74fY5JG6FWpRWK63qaWMP55XI6QxmBZbNJ7PxZYc5O3@/ff1QdA1@@yaeuxtQE7v39d0azLeu9d5991Ov9/xpjt77x6g1@7ufRBqpmOv0@@EETttuFyItXtf1Y@H06sX5Hq/3a7o9lKvz7fbOd254tWetk3EEGK9BMzCq48JDdu74LV7v72tL1sJRQG2kccM4d3B684Q3nf0DvOKLupF35NOh69CMwBVppniUPvCxUzYPI@BZzvZoW54bhXtkxqR6eL7aaMgt6rUgwxBfZKrF@jfS@FTxzH39Nm0ManJrdqkVlTZSFsvxTcnat7is2vDLaWcr6zpW4qay0wquLzO7SVJUlC2SEq5vfGKpB6lt1RQotb45taWwDeU1lah@GxjDAWPjy1VKVVyskrSzKoVKxBHTsqE4CPdKLa2ivnKLHKxmNEltVIsgvgH9AlAiOjgIHebpFKnpn6cTiPqdJAU8kMzTqY001a1l5pkJzWGJJmmq5OaUmVnWBP5CrRUqosfRhgbeIAOYUD7AHACWhQuUEzxSrnEAw6ShEs5ceiOEecsJ5cuzs78s7PmRcwqJTDNhqk/@MLR8dHRh8CtQCqZstG9ejjA@8QzkedFK@bfvb8r7j@ObPjNA/EeCsiuJ@4ij1vwYZJy5HQEipR4H7p2UKIjN4gTeK4t7tEV9iBlRx7RwUNieC6xeHR/Ac7hwD1lKUMkv4qCnI4nLuAnIawu0Wt1MOldkqJYET19SoWKdr1ea9eG5nAUTCGLUazPE/q9hBmYfZ/hTj9R0zc9QqOf9Tx3GHq0a/JFtVObJCaCQHZAxht7WYDYrhFBeT50u8/VjFHt4jch7tTuIJhqG96dqlkzPc/1eNBi@Wpvy6mNHV/vmU9MD4@R2H@8DsIOnsyS6hEzvU6aexh6F3WrC6HuEWeG46PxMKUL9U560QknRWIHJFPqC1H2z3BSADDn@Ytqr0ZSzyDoS7B76yTVFe@kt3JVoNgd0k6Dk/y897xHVFLIVakqlEJY0AQppZACerpW/zzIaAz0MXTigE1Y5McAFRMDwFAa1EdPj6yLqlGzSUogkzSlUa7arzUw@jk@NgWebwlC47yFcxofoH7wcgydZx2ae3Wa0Gv@uEO/EkTkjqLKheoE3JRirjqA8tafTapebTT2zKoN1nAWhNAc61WgLZAQwLw6T11@5aP0ppCvMbcqBXWOQ9dtsV2bVB083xVqSk2rgUemkZOzeVxVmy9mQYRQC1mlkNWyuaxQRFeQH@geC1TFWmtrKTvFE8Jn5YksKlnFVLIp@bnVfZ7OHqdQzKHES2cDd88ZDwm6QJFhbaV2eOvpjLoBJOq6RN8UaOUFJlPFfAHtB2RkZQcU0oGp2yxCWiDaRspeT2Gg9aPxaK/RqlT2JqMvgFdKeLlVyBTlzKt0uppaS9d88yWdMbpjQQXRgbjImWj2R2tQp8OZIuKPhw0odTApRbXSaHQwr0U5q8kaZNNqn/c3@TrfysprBQXK7IJOCCiEcZb5uRGQnLiZ26iNuoJtQhkqZbXK0a0lCXLHG9PJGq2kCmUpv5GX2QQJA8GNQhaJtCWpZrQ7J5lKJotqMjlTrNPJKk5Gr/GzuUGqbp9RDpkElk2St9V8YYsHAZCv8GWVh2AzjotYEjnCfAMEUtPXPZxE4nC4guRAXT/jLs4uNuvcROT2hpZt6VniWAZ@bs8yjkXunut1s6Rj9UlPD7Ati9wO5Ha/InKHoOuZ1NTYw08uEBafHqCC0VohwAqdYQsGUxB/PYg/pROOgXjdFUqJ4DtKajEE@Rx3iOdvbKrP8Fd89nDnMf7ubSdwywrZ/hz4lcG99Ozh08dPH9@jZyzMtj5/lmubIxLdlzIR29VElY774@oMSAazVvkMi7@3cQ6eSGt4eADJiIJYpwdUbLNUmuFRSdIaIZ9140xms/6MvZu4eRRAc/S89wZp0aXjpoWqOnlfB4FyiyShyHVv2FBVrdVQiyCWQNfVkFlQVVWqgEU7QXdC16F@T84A6c1MHY@h@DyZTvWMEGX9Nqn3M@uyOk2ctPlCWaMnJbTrinxM1pK3N/BD5gJJnByv1dWNTPJJRcsk7ya1XOIk1VyvZ5RpUiIbGXXaw3VquCJKSkI41dy4pW0kn2YqpX62omTwqcKzkiTCWmK7nd1Ol32O1mSSWCDwWnmnttM/2ImW8u/s1kvqNDw@I/GszZeKIYrNdSCZmnm2vRC/DrLQM5y9vVJuP8tK/21cGZ@sJhNnSZJIXiQvGskWgG404tNYaq0Z@risL1z7oOUKJJ0g6dBWLCf8VLzw4HPJ7UQSZ/eJ77@GCk3LgTbr6KCEzz9XgckkHDdycMcBjvSCGJXP49x1Qno@8r@olrSH@4@du949k0s0187XXFyXQKo8A8mT1857XyBkBKWVJM1aYlLLhZO/Sr0uKJsqHpRWJBUQAHpKQZDP64yT1alHQQWfy698JzfZLIFdlRWwq2o@o9brygaIoInR5Sc/CLwpOdt7f@cBSeJU8o//7Htq8cd/9vt0@Xzygk4vq1oxASHRqBSKibOz0dkZCIAXzC@faCWuLQVsAZkkRS8XN8RqhUilUnlDbEuJcB9jSikq6YQvJMJdFoW8kEopkpre0EpyGnzOwwOoUqpcAmu0zIM68YU8n07sHVh5Vdne3IKcbWk5tbrWaPBKPCJO4t@m6ZcTXKL08Pk5IWAx6t1@31KpSZLCNvRaIJuvhU14Qwm/FtbI81od1zMqeOxLtGJgA4@MwCU8yXpG2kgS0LNJvXFRvWhl6LIDOvLxbMNpXiFGcw33GC86bTjwMzd8@jNNaqUOPlgjm7nxwudTG2lJ6nZpn4NLPgShnmBVtm2SfB3qy4YEWG5EqwTYTxCa6cuv/KaqFn78Z79y3j5vf6iqarlcLihq4qc/3Rw7Y9/s1n8KEZ9Ex/9BJTKsLlbWI/fYdHwxHm@gHZ3l4OfWLCcepyDsYEIrjBUbRIPnEmMHdTEWPhq1wPEJAvKo1XfMLh2t4E5QmqbF2maH63VTNNgGAWUkS3U5eppXuspxkZ7DdDWvb2QpDLKBp2M3WmnujHsHvXAXLeh7Ve6dGShwGII05hpt3x57I7o3O0XjKa0suQ1RIIV38DDDNQidJmGfLQAXhn76WlSGsk@pRuVtgge549GIIIpw70CU8DR/e0pGuuebNKTlgJwgYhCKJ/Xo4s6pFqRtswht6pqiuWcBsoRhxyI5oMJx74BsSalggchJrE0IUAWe8g4QAPKQCgFbLbJJtDQ5szKZ6uzcxQs8UcdxgYTRIYAcRkNoXSBTHLmK4cAJVEf8ZDHWi7CEge/NOUZAGAy2hq8GyidGpzYU5i2oDpO3BgWwTgdYQjRr5PbtGVa1mtVNE5ojhH9sjXC8lpaDsxxXABZp8beApYI4lclgYb@zWO2A4hmKLtQ6gR1lWZ2LSni0XnAc/N@60mKNvFJU1KOKGQjLi7UKA0gGkZHsrAwNslkjilpMkxh5A3A3KFL0iKh4aKI5uSWqH0aeF4DhTxPR18eAWR3Nj4GH9fauaZ8Pz2OC@wQUsDE9kTcY6IwZdE3bGuLiQByxRqa3H0Sx41iQFcumoXuWB2owXSoYnZ2Y0pQ0RpudNUnxoFsb1RzBfYf5NL5oLAxN4K3jWX5hOmtUdDVcKFB/5Dr08L8AWRPu8YQaATwKEnjkBiZDe@yc4icBw7KhkecxglyCloM1HzGmhxm6jumzuLjiruOZ@nFEmywx@yIxhl2ilkmKVjQHl5Y4Mbg0jUQR7oD2hDTu2OYQUDo0TXpEgl@RpD4IfeMOzotLDy2oV4N7FnQ/ji/dZQSWTq1jSzrC498Ft4cnKVDgAAXkRGx@bM0eKJpju0ts1z0mtnVssqmN1PxBiviVlUIWFJ8sUHZ2A2ErKPKqWhYHwZQsCwV3EV5FZixl5@Kupabp629NWUu1sUTPaQ9mQanY5onuzNGXXudcOJDiT32OnhtZI6g4pMAuxiwXWiY7gi2JpyIm0yLQvgsSFi1fH6JgTBGnzEYpPsGnRX9kWwE1ciPPPCE4EMJhHwNM02iHKGArhty@QzsA2vagZeFZjoFXgZLLACZeN2VA0wsZvENuEU3lMCCkjEEZAgADi762CB38ICrmww@6UDAinSdCvgKtc9gFPzwrLqx@GD@q3WimJ2vOqjdZC8Fhp0PTqhHWLCJLfs6CrQPrM836GngWAMMlmKyl@AyAzfBpnoGO41@Nzmo7R3lJhVyHlCUIISQ1QKGigo4sBw/FnvumHy4kuaMDd8bPNmCth0p/enoq0mNLx54lmj5@5853Hd2WRn0LxGFXCszhKPwSuGVIowjuzCSwz1iKo8Foa4JCba18e8reHNfza@ES3FSy5yexczzBz7j1hyeoWwHCPf//be/r99NGkkX/jp6ig5MB2eLLiZ0EG89igxN2HZMDOJlczLAyCMwEEIOwDZPx@Z2HuO9xX@W8xn2Ke@ujW2oJYTvJfJzd35w9Ewupu7q6urq7qrqqmhjqeEhXPXZT0iWY@W@7bX1W/FdIUg7A5C0CEQLBLKyl1bUAmHXR/WT1b3p78sM1TUgADqPoqJeYTHimfow99TSc9v0S7hzXUf/TxegT@RQApASfFgRNcw9VyaX6KX9Ph@i7P3FuRGk2s5cp@m5iaWTg1JLEHrGEbZ@@wCNsM@IzZ7YdLlrLdqj6wq8Om5rvVQQLeQp3rjuBcppj/L7g7wv4vuDvi6BR1Wxr0WaRDF/dYneQ6zEIQZVEMEtV5pZTAgdfCDLI4SLPILDkMvQOXZW7Raqt6M2/YByLijGAJ6ZAcCeVbf143jpvTzznZrO9lR0AsyeIEDDiALrVJpre9PxnpP7oejR1vdAr2D5IvJF446vupeQG5hXsoz9AxBhMryGmcR2MpbcTCwSywwAB5TD4iKJBaZ4amnt@rm36CIzTSgQ0ZsRaEpk2SV/yk3wH4hKTngmrA2prgPC93yVAE74INXP4VlO1OnyYuVBGlU3TRYywRC5Fsp0ESkamCq81ezRIGlbptEITyI7iajHaFfUdhqIV@aR181aOv47@4y9Gvw/zIh57YljeMPYMfapgwAGIEHK6EFXFQVEbV8Agu2mPnBnsXBWWT@VuDc1sZpWawe1gF7yb4bx7mdIGv2vy@FCOi8QkUfBZYVksQheXRZ6WPC8USZngfjVPVlsqRpD1eQEBGLnYao6sttCrLYpFXjjEYk21Gw3JBSG54CpcerEGybasBtpTVW0vODxtkE4xEiIB8PK8jYIYNE0Iz7520Ivjp6vxFLUq1Waw5hAXSB5CERv5rNuObb2lIa0tWhEAyIgrAHp84XnBiC54@bT/y1@jmJRqjeJfkg14rQAGoyV4z2AdyGcy0oFB4E9s0T4Aczex1TISeTomwP/l@L@EpV6q//KrL3Phkvnwy5wV@d/v8rKNlNUmqCZ95HPPcUE2AkuFbrJ464I2GNghNIcJ7RUeFIXfwQIwoWKswY0RSooUtzvNC2Rf4CnO7IEfSYoKVk5YoqQ@xguNlTjzKB04NSIoFdwN6Bnnk4S5p91IoKwMwcYoxHH1pCI2KeilT4KzEpoTswRLKYzG4@HkLgToZI8kb5xEZLV46hXgP8DBUiCBTGS/SBFtzHtxI4pcXPVblC5LTgTiU4GpygJsEME@KMcTPFq3Ek89kbC@g4omMm6ldmwa4dT@8ogkVB@Q86aTFNSyEulMgqrCO0w1g5DCIHg08b1CGFBG2VQpYqhQ4F1@GbrDyFlAVyYDhxQzO5t/mdt9ZVDvJtbcGrdeta3NbjEhYAmyJ2PvanbT@zRwL6/7YiSmP10sustffhZi57nAvJ/b33EwZn63mKXQMQrSFa9ydCmDRPB7CjfFpOoZZc5OCrqOgaMXHgu6GkKQn0IBZcIIl4rNseJCNCrMi@PWbrs4gUV43Jq099CsMd8qzrfyWyl88V3exHxKWDPVbc3bQJdbbRZtGq9t0GrwelFRuvDo4BP2NCNkLpjDDunhCSwdXOCdU6MhCPrETDekkMpIQVBWgGEDiPqd30a1j5o9lbfwSar3UCkjagj5ZohCif/BwxsKPdph8Xh1jncMAEg86gIJg1L8wy77bJuVdkdgj7AU7NoDHQkccTTH4PT3Lw7IGPISBYO7Sn1B4xheDy1QccUTf9ipC4bxH1fD7qej12I7l3uRzz3LayTDO4ERwVzm2fNguwIiqQ/b6OKzk39uGEfudMlue7CZI6znaQRoiRNUjt@DXuZcO5OJY5RGI/bv8/CuC2d27fQyhlF3euQ6enFFFEE17grJBVqtezXr8gUJF8OJPVsiX@CNLnSlAkx@/It@iWNQdfryEkTLQCsIKGTj4ZxtJe71EC8i8S0/fXc0cm@QYF00ujA9sNLYgT3O2DRFGCUklsKF9P3xlTfHKY1WYwRoX@CVvV2fDBPY/LowMmTCMEYAigx3WmOTXgQTaK87slHVysQhAA1pFFAIQNd6V13nThwMQuILcRCyYypcw1Yjk3VnhktzZWyjagtyXUBgGhWqpuEOA9x8U22IRu24@aFUrwh4flevva@WK2Vx@FE031TEUe3dR3LKFW9qJ@VKvSEwqvWodtqsVw/PmjV4kSg1oGaCPhil04@i8sO7eqXRELW6qL59d1IFaAC@XjptVisNS1RPj07OytXT15YACOK01hQn1bfVJhRr1ixqVVUzgnqidizeVupHb@Bn6bB6Um1@pBaPq81TbOwYWiuJd6V6s3p0dlKqi3dn9Xe1RkVgx4xytXF0Uqq@rZQz0D60KSrvK6dN0XhTOjmJdLT24bRSR@RDvTysAJalQ9gesSXqZ7larxw1sUPB0xEQDxA8sUTjXeWoig@VHyrQnVL9oyWBNir/cQaF4KMol96WXkPnjNQ9VIFxOTqrV/AkCinRODtsNKvNs2ZFvK7VykTrRqX@vnpUaewJ46TWIIKdNSoWtNEsUdMAA6gF3@H58KxRJbpVT5uVev3sXbNaOzVhkD9U8J6YoxJULROBa6fcWyBSrf4RoSIdaAAs8eFNBd7XkaZErRJSoQFUO2rqxaBBIGJT76Y4rbw@qb6unB5V8HMNwXyoNiomDFi1gQUAJrb7oQSNnlGvcZwAL34EZjUU51o0nKJ6LErl91XEXJYGDmhUJbcQ2Y7eSJpn0LlWE9CGeO2kY491oa2/@uraQYewVWkvXv7zz5@OauWKSKhzw0Tw4Qx2nZeRgyn9G@w0/kf4GToA6DkXV4MOXtKDErtfjYWqsTewMKsDplQU58Yd59RSdqMKGxudzvtSp1R/3eh0TOshNUNo3FeD0q1iXtn1pUzZR4w3QxsaCpWFAtN9P0Sog@9QHOw7M0uwEzKVZOp/R5vrxB6DrpjN9hxZDU0hCFiJpbAHz9yxAGA9XBrJCovx70GTJPXQ76FkB6qYUuAz3Q68xp5zIdeDfya/Bj94c9BewOrMonQ2O3DmjAYoqKoZboQMTPSPtO@A9kWSvOc4nwapnN6cM@mZGbzRCr0jZR0qO3dGo0HKvKf6hTOIVE9H6xOyaNRUKZY9Di5g7QIZk8/BJMmEHJfMjHqWwn86c/pjKmzYgoaGEmqKTPBSIUp9x9VbuTaSlQ2FIFHzIKPM97b0Q/UDKrm57ed7kfdv/Pc8t9BhEH1LYcNrUb02/XnT5gIwwciyCSQZSntjNqvVAbGMBEq/8A0UvMRCfCMX7tWXDu3rQBIQZK/skd4m7saz4ULHHtbh1/XS28Oz42NYOhHb5y93XuzuGf4h5g8W//2I7ZB3J53hTmEfBzmNPmmz5AgEH5opmit@wP7EwNksFsRgDjVo9BKtZv61VywkcB4MkqX2sbseJoOYoBkk4Uzoqi4yZz42FL/GzkzJAKlQV03szdhekIhvg6xEPCAPTUdLGrUF/oOw/emvprjfIclAksXI3xU413jE614CK9FJW9@9mvAxCBbJJBQf86G4TwO8x0vkC/IYkX5J3tZGEQRbHGicrzTsVBOQeBzFQkg9lDy7oYl3ZLWVyiWdxcKbHyS/weNH6S5AzgO2Ny/NG0DGY78m6sCBois73ZKQ2xhch0fUqqV9gRYEUyJFc0@qqr6ZVZsNhArGvaJ1Kgx4z7fKRptERTj5tyTo28ypaApFOHuSY@Vv4Ny47kgoe8oaK38rG59gWL7JmKl247dhqCIffaugImeITN9ED4L/J9IkBv4@aJwAPaCW5lLxIEoSVKYVqK9ElOGNMmJolpOAmvqrjwGYW31gLv2OScvQglwJkARydJbqxUdyIumnYgiATG6iZ4E2f3uuQ5euw84MqtPfEqasjjaYSXc8TQm5V6itYgVuerdtkdhlKbsN/jCFSYZZoTV4AlXF31hxu6BZDypTRJUXT70EgzOVNTW7iecZwYQnLkWK5NVkDzgrJ2eZWgfkwZW24fT88ycQS2/XWgQ3heZwFFr7pVVNEQpAHyA@q/2kKENXdEeu50T8V/jWiCb5FKDnviUvW5QOAOhpgC5OCOdpT8h7DJ35DW4QI4ZOjg8BNJF6Sr4X2AgfSwSCg1puzQyQlrbVGx/7BWF/o2F/NuH4EvpZEKpEhn1MJIYTvIgSeIbuJxdv7SWgPHpYt5nFspsN1xI3DkXxsFlC1segy67rzkB0tLHfgKM1XJoZ8UEaHZyJdzWT3iCwnw1n0iKhhH5oBsUm1t5pm@G4DULNG4LcMEebC/IHdWns2BPpIDJcpHdFCphX8egBsjC5tSy28iK1H3zZB5qQkxcRcV/sYpI1KsUElQ5YDlFw6PnKBcwSl9vZF7lg@t24s0@496MINOk5Pd/PSwMJL9QgVSfkMdOdc9enrkcWDRgKtID4lMizIe3C7n66Qckb9ugXkp1AQMdXicDXCD3BqCdf3o7PpBIqNhQwrmwdmG83DYOJVNqWjla@61V@e4dQiVO4btcqY@R7FTaJi8T5xF9SCvK22KdKdMQnXjf9p4/4xLcFOsWnHs4eeIP2cymCIsIos6LNdnWdI/zwvOLD0Jn1dJsoSDI9e4rmN1J93AnxojIdSieKrj33nCVoAN3scJElGJ3U393LSefIHdmDoTu0QU/D0IoFr3j4uKRHHLDBzL3xKJ6YEydphXrL4Jms4fJQG39Ljx38GRx0enNnmtKPQOazZQmjZ1GLoWN8PGv19yvi72n0xNmv83wnqOTXITwy0yvvEnTTvbV1n@XjKvNpAQKQC9xB5HSGjskd9HksqpbcaUo77lAFLu4qoOF4IdLC1j7frsX4FZCIDnhDGCtkVo489E6gZrYW41ZvYfXIo2PmzmHdKjsYs@ql6LVlY1pPgRdpv8rhRdovc1pVypnZW6BXBz4s15N7@8WfjD0g8A3o55/FcUscI9AS15ezAdZkUiakzxbgQu7MQ1qjaSWGVWw4gF1oFALaWUShhj8v11GDThVBKJJOCytciTMyBYoPpr1IdWDJ6SzpnvWkSJrkKIAiSIku0VnHsI7OrLp/jd4OHnFziF0GF6YjCTmlIb2OVF2gEiYEDMGcXukos4fq/TNme/uhoxYhYFESMISDliszlVCSC3pi8/3VczrWcmewGCci1JOnkklv7k6TD6Te2rUj9pw7jtZdcx2RPkeYrQib5WaPSFtc4uNyz4jiE2GaMMXoFBt4CNVXevbZPErERbGD863YWd5Dh3U0C85k/U3FH@8ez33cFK8xrFRtNP6UItzR5WvPf9/qQMc761cQCZPVqw6tGB1cMjpLftRARcjkU@nhFCLuk7hH6NEDymG7PaCdPj5riRo9gFcOZOpTyGUI6Ylu8PbYwXVp2s9AR1KmOp/yFylf4FxYSzrKy6cv0GUTPzBAlIqddGCHYgtuMFgRPqJYi36qg26BeVyJ4OmAfXaV55NE1CcYxThI4w6797Y6y3S@vceQFj4k0Cr4Yvc7IMlXWKzVWRCUFVLAFI8hhd@jlbXp8uG9@ta@QDmAwLXps3eFR/AgTWFnTLEF2MA/@qfOAmXgoClZMzSjwhOhQ0sDzAXQUgYjh9VVlP6GM@Z4vOVHTiNQIPg1XeKzJWugc/Ruzqc2Vln0lljElOTm2WZirjSqEjAU/0byy6nIoi4prgDAkbfUwfzIAwR0EiPs8VBg5PTnIc4LISrHCCoW8zgt4SX5mAU@JDHfkaiywPMdrUQursQrHUY6FggIFvFlAkRAZokvEkCBjS4WF63Ei/j@BCVAIFa8zxSHoZCjEqahP3JMQMqjlzODFaWVF1ZOcjB9fL5jhj76/E1fX@W0r7noV6CPj2ErnY9@fZkLfQ01u70drhqqCfQw9VZDH4EUpo6wvyp82/8Z5BKoOZArCXdfUzJCUob0/cI8h6Blgt6W@ckT@2jiOFAyhoJHh3HpPKmKSv3qcMBayMX9bnd2kaQjA/SE/@beqpgNhYmMvEieT8jRno27rBCSxJrArR67hZoueVOg4YQ8TkC/VTqt2xfvm8fHuhIsLpbK0WjszHZyuRwy8YUeSqD8ttCUNHSz4dLZ/tVolJ3e/H32/iJLaz9mzB55bkFp0A4MCUwKL@POBhxngzhAUSydBgKP3WsHdf2rfl8PaMETShw8GDYuyb5iPUEb0NB3ennf5OD642CD/Sd2EPv3T@HPvhubBU0JRR1DQW2g3vl1Qp2eAXnwRR99v/yTKgKGC7PyZoJ9yywefMYdBOPEaLDIGdREs5Bk/8QbZzRyLfEBM5I9TpBFJVLh@FivkOMieMKIREEXoxFwmCWc6@EoOJ/ysIjO6whObUwqakd52WOkQd0ZVBbTVKL1YwK2FejyFnZzC719LZEYJEzpev8AsMyHgPaDSo/taapLdIoWhq1ezuDgCTB6lrdidZ9QEZNsYpJm95dGosajm/nJHU5S0HWTZAEVGUDDSz1ZU9wnbuJ8ke8jDXMMQ@JE9wU@qMbt3rctjd@2LF7P@/2HrYoUVMED@0UrIseVfduCSGcANAPl9AN6YnTlP9IwrY8jgVAs4GDo0@q6gxU6WMEwnnaLP9@kSqWSeDLd2hKl0iE8YJKfw5Io44vDQ1HGDCr4@7vi9s7OHq@5ZfMzvDxUL2/FIcDg24u7l7My/IRvRQxwg@2etMgn2eITa@9Jp7h/sOdlW6XDdjY7gCe@Xypbkj/w4qnsIf1o/egXymQy2Sfdz0@@u93D361yO/nkovVk2k4O9pDLgAylq7lbnaftwH00M7swNngX0N6SH6nSsz3M5CqrCpUeYWzPPsHqUhAbXS@7Id96HIdLa@xG19HeOxNMggIqvArhiKryBobIj@0lmuNhdLoOOuDBfkNpXMkPlOvz2Yoy3E9crYB/qrJBCEiZ9doB0HjCsYROcsMYP4A3MDsTtIBfk8zL3TMMG/4O5x3Jv9kf5b0Pm@cpsZkTm5bYTCToD94BsXluPskO8W4RLubfDhEcLaCbofCGJOiR/kCRixFyG8YTCoBESCocmgpPrsYXaHxW2h@GT8rwdW9gPKKLSNlEQodMWGXj85PJLQzLZyhxmzAeUThjHvN@sKDQkVoMNaadqPjjiyKQ7bEjQNDymAlScKFJPOmDynzml1Vv5FgbFJtJgJGs9dfHNO/xBexFTyimMx/RpTBolIIf@S3ujXscvEto4xduP0CADlRYncxR2EhyI4lnHXS9gN9L6qagGE@9f5L52Ndh6cyxYtD8fwqNCejTI51wTyb0js4x6SPTPzH0j1e0phJclqLt@WTG0KqMr0bz4XQkz7yIRDhyfmu3PJNwRAkQw@EI6sLqDCNDAWY@uHEoDFkfFg49Xoqei13nmSDTreJ0MDN8cqQRIftjCub2r5G5bWaHiIliB@YBQsp35evbw5GHJJ@rvK0De3aBuRYoR7MYzvncjOx5mFMngrHb95HOEGRyOQ/mM3RlYzqzB2PbEhunbnNmL6uwbYHkM@9mTOjhJDknJHDyyabjuqcQ5h7JISGK@F0hzyGM3h4tZbA5jy2OBg0GDamaCjJBA06CEDsRJZ1fQ2MVoWPA1V8wCDrKK4u3fxopl1haedHTSEIKugD/0DRbmTqGakGfO/7ESRiMqj8zFS/ISle40Y7p4BdWckzqrdqmmo48HxSwXGL7uDsNnIkd2pymI8PgxCRPsnuC90Wcz5TYg72R5J1F@Rf5IH8AYgVy5I/hK4R5b3L7LLMZj1KpR@eeDI7f0PcRFJ4zvi9@1kZWlWflFA4@poR8Z5MhL5aRHWrItAcmzIgqef4DhP7IHgB@yxt7iax4vpH6/nHWbP14Pmlvps4nv57/YhImcklWu2xabMjDbLViybkCO2PWCv1UXmkekABzJ4rzSbjA@YTcuvj0XpIAEMmmWj9m279mAaHzDdPczJ5vMEFCQ4aYZO9uL4vgsytoboSxyG4Yj8xNUw1@6vu8KWBvpb84hvzC5L@AhVIqyUwPes6sD6AoBojuJ0DFLvtyO/d8O/8cNKGBs0jPnCvcb9Pe1YWzAFHCQ3UWtp7zX0LcECLE7cKz9@DlAvo5HEwwFTSNqCcTWsglVE5zasfw2QrqZJgnoDxQOYUkwBAX0y9j4@EjKvyWAJZTZSmjBbsOatyXwv3Tc8fYju3huhaNDmGORC8D9hEhE2oaIUvGW8uhppouSQo2y4ijSwcGGYHA8GY3tN1i4k7SUlgzM8k9FKIxamaEeX2jc3RlioZm6BMpTCUfi/zB9y/@@3/Xft6YbxxsZz/M4O984@eN3Zcb/AgP8OuZ@nW9cbCxj8V2bzeWWdCB4fHFf/8fqH/wd4CDX5b78M/BjoK1u9w4SBepyq8bB7vwkN/ehnb/73/9F/ThCWtsmNnmSccShNieosiRPSHehe@iir1ktTQZLCt5XFgQBnsYgm4OP9AxarH9Mkdmug3pVXGN7j/D/tz3R5FbPDlmzclViC0Zyp8CJCOuUMQG0gxSuVD0hea7odw2kHkDNMU/n2Z2PdAA/indOfwmfdeNpx66DD1htQgGMMUtgj7PDwe57xO@e0choXxK9pQIiaqdXGtfPtsDdnjnOvNhN@wloabruGvfOBcZ5MOM07sCnWrijdyfZtlrYMlxfvtlto/G/Sz5cWenBCk9XWZ@AUFQZiMBxZCcTi0xgxFwx/AXnjFHCQj0x/6ZlMrOAVL21OmyDSuc4QmKNJrlSr1u8fEwdicTiNIp@hcEeMxDItNqaJHn5xOoWasXRGLLL8jlSOc1EZt35Bwrk46k2RuWsteCAEN9QOug6k@mNBtQEBLVmgEELpKxe72OLb@ljEcJFXhuGY8undG0mCDfMOgN3qwGErqkP4uZa6Gkh2hBSKdpoUNYY2dug4peTNAb1MeDFuZ4QwGftZJuTKuLT9a@LCu1@l7xGM@07mj6hpu@gRFFKSFox@eZIBfOROjFeG0poqly5nTwSC22YWjNUymwZhn6gxh4PCzVPoYlyO5QBCRQLeiO9CrTh80iXRh45MbhmD02LXIeMGMjCH60VAngrOppBmUnbDfDjcECcepOnAJ6KPMNeBgBUVRJW4YTEoBWPqvYYQmG@lCbOoymIhR2xJLb0gT2QxI4MJZSAAmGjsebWuCDbfDu4YOWcLSEPgk0vCRMZKl@gZQtKqiGo0BJtbhx1MzYTtXqCj9ZT1/mAqK73fBFIpfffvZ8Z/fFy1cYM/5I9jYeDFbKoBYwvbQBBknUKVCy8X2xmEgm@BUm9FptEqHHgcUDOHTrujEJK358jFcLMLBcgmDdUGIqri7NlQQygDhzMrgjgI6SmiVSqe8LLexY@7xn/gr/JSxVmxkOTc32aPiLzaTXxuEdB0RQmqOxM3ZneDyOC7NNmV0wpz5sIfxFL@u4/bqD91ahryuzPTR04roYlDBzrwaXOndk2NovmjBhgODz2bJAGtRrhyNFSafWsEJZVBocqlr0RVHBa632AJ1ycUtAmY@BwzSDyYBe/rb0NMXZkYRNCPM8YMQqHiFqrqM6OxN3TlxROS1HEZOZ0IaeDzeje7aCcAf7IYCv1I4x85HW3SZQF6bEQPZarUkWG/RJ95ULXA7LAVcg02OsdBfTemlUUWs1yQ3z1F1kyRMvDv2EdkFVGEfEKwZmPnc/KVVcq@oFEkQthNKa5C9iln@eo5MswEkfZJynyMuJguYj@nboeZTLWzaWMKVHKRWCgfT4VCIOINptcgnuSK6AI0qPFUpjxaPNF76SyyTekcoD7GuqTmzJYV@aCihqnDOL@LTA/ldPjyxRrsA/xx/KFgrKh6V/YL/9hFnr8c1LfPMFUT1WQ0AElWY48rlFn6mfMUQJmCVncfqSAEFcfMmwgfVI8kYKVqrHkvY8qVuhud0OuALZ1ZZCuLKOykmCWVPIBvJIKu9kOpO5FqVCX2Dj1epKsyULq2nBJq67J7ZGk0dBqz4kJuUDQGxHQaQViIDbHwUMzx7oJHnbUndRjF09jufpEMuyQgVi@3EWyB7m2bWUuYsttiVbbBdwHO/iC@LbO3mD7y4LM8c9vPH463gj/XDmSP9bMEflz@GOZ5I7nhVw7WHumHRnDq1IFNFJSe3cGI65WNIe3OkNB0O0D/W1n9iJnKUBoAWPriSzKR4kn8O@rVlORCr@w1Z0P0Inoe2dXeMrO/9cdv55Addceiw7/1M7n/6NO78jO79TwL0mZuSlaCfDX3@7HgciYSr8InZ4UdzlYubX9nRX9nS3gLtpzDD/4T1N/049fSF7@qKAGRP4wIFTuN7NzSyJlBpH1WrgbpFRGYhTmBUwnitN1L3wWmxL9EdX3mURpXXx1fi/lPi/xNWInupIVluLUfZ1eVZPOVieJUu@OA@DrLgn3F8Z6qX3V25YgT4iNyhepMmwNZOKCgjkFn8MTpsygfwYrL7@5vNQnHltp9xKnBlWU6BZI8ybwRRnyZcKqwSsj5iR52hJO2rWT7b@F5NhbH@SUWiAPA7tDd4xJHcSXQXDseLXsjNadxB2Q@ocIVaR5CRk5zLa22eXR@tXNUpsEdkX45UEPmrjdMmYgcrRPIDIZAS0ycj6SqtC11ylXvAb6DsXiu@y7PFXcekryaWvCqIuFYN1pLKlwU/yYqCnbe/s3LUHcK0M/sEJmLOg/B2z6v8Fhwur7h@lPlKn89bxvA0tWZSh5@nmMgLLiHCZ0hWUmRXwupjJBfofvPeTT20bWrZlUFY8wzh6W26g7cK@6Pac/uBy@NOn8cSd/jzz5lfXN4vlL/mEYajk/CmTsxYq7xtppljN15yYJSJJm9Na1uYABBrmk2w1CRtCkvl80mwVCtttU@D8HHM@Jj4fCACQiDrxRnhHErlZ@NnDaSjZgyEa2@vR0b83x5hzIFlqZI8verZYFAT6X6fzlkBvMPm2C4QEEpEdJtWF1XNqmibdCSOvnEjqkAtJS/@pd3U2GFfZPicSCYkS/KzSgQAaW/yivoWmRSaXttgE5uMvw17YUsI2Gb@mTK2HaoHk0@3nbbMAZPpAX5DhL@3RnE8EU7@YvieMM/cjCXDrPOJFDneRnBkKXNCQ3qcN0O@YKZkjOOXi/mrraui71o4PoxWAb4cKh2il/diCqe@H7gAwmAruoeuOTnB8VQuWpIYlXgadCTIhYljzG3vU90dBZSseslNliHfCfaQcskjt0MBECCGJ0fdXuiCY@hKbdaWl2K@Phw2A8QW5K6yA0vHFSisFVriE1tBQTh/aNKL1eHi9OacTj@lEwJwtHwnKER3wm/Z@Q/xQq8PoX9uzIRq22NqWhzYyTgbm54Ac/udyMsUmKpKTa3sH5pUPmWaYuYJcfJ/WoZxafQl6r3yJDdC6gx3Ay3NVF3A3G1B2w/uRfgDKd0znEIcyWGTvY9iOfPZWTJ3flUJdMolIS/kxbtqFuRtZe4Y@xqmXkcFWdMDptYvkUi/aLK8En1/iOGPOMdgDZja7k22Is/kQFvFl4NNMwg05jOlSFiUhYmCcmz86gbuXlriQP2R@HYmptnggbShP/6UZJBpf0zkFrMXuGFviBZ65E0P4EEGAwxmQN@NWRGzM/5kV2@b67kIp7Ke3KlhGuhwa1Pjuulc6Arl7@xmUV0@wh@jr@Aohhu0wC6xCUEutdB3GvUF@WuVsPJLqdDD3T6dDqVY6HZQfOp0kt8LChCYEafdelC56V7P0zL4c2/bk79mu56Xx4u3p3DC6QNb9fZGsnJaTGGrlf8pMlzAO6c20kHn6BYkc@MZIJMJRpkeNhmgc1avvmoK@GTQmXXc0cqR4IGWk2qyH94OWh925EptYylO/xjamFTLoQkpx5HkNwoV7iIPb6aD7f6eT8pxRXxudjeAJ/nvTfHsimpRwsFlpUD7ERkxRhJHBAEhSTxHx/cfl2lHz47sKUHE8OjD21R8odED19ufD@cg52M/yX37nzZcoCiynDmiB8l2WXkLdLFfev3B7S/jTG14L@lRMqKP/wswBcWt47exBZZ22hGDfdecBglmoj0AltCwjqCrolUGQq5VroiDsHh7ZgCColAecVB4Ghgz7S5F8lswMPdLrU2a4ZXnziZRGk/wzgy0mLZG82UrGbP3hgWi8KQEtX5/UDksnmPHrXaWOaSzXjcXFoANMgxIsXcuQDH/l8DR3EhIq6MtcSqzRj@FSP5BoHH73MfxuTTfqlddVzOe4HnMmaVF8zhXyt@FP1@hTFfuFLqGgb7erGKxB5fik9PpOLFCpW9n36CtamGO/rmmqdvq6hikoMXXmuhbdyQA0jUEHW44hr/qMTXfwog7vQfRWLR/WynfQfDDizkQbxcZwejyoqaPa2en6xUG6COfDUDYMH9Gz5ruzphGu6S9WMGFonbLEQluqtKklfVIW5jr4h6VGRVROKOOp9ol8XUbOWEG3xNLiRQVUUFo7HQ9EF0slKkQxphCNa6ZrVWOXI/sC9OerubOHcaCFz7fTxd7cncoHnGqY47fAsa6pz7c9Z2DunRufbxPcdjEBDJ04@HzLi9X5JMlX0cxTElF9Mq/g7SNtGhFilCv16vtKWdGjoX0OlQSiVY/UV59e3eGsi3FzGsUo/4wls8/EjFBqZROmL0R5hpAkEEwZBsPP6Hc1mKFXbZomObzdu3Bx84NduDe88go7uad7Pl0kIivNMUhLXxwjSddj5ATVYfQu@xO7@5t1jvqCsOt3dgjEWtBKL0aYuAL@G/3uHTw35IheuPO5O05TWms1vFwr9B0nU@izDwAm1/ra@DGmarQnX0PuFZI9iLfUNKPUzsfVI97kGyD1l@r12odGZDVc4Ut7NnNvzqa/D2uKnBo3eJIUpFVMIN0ErGvDnjg3aBWjC@zm/rzkWlqxmEI8lLLUucHldGZHXYIwMbPbdBFh8OubJjMRrezeTP4lyYa7x@9KszCd6ljpjyNU0Ls76BTinLWE0mj@h3PXCbT9L0k0nQV/J6qtX/MoZfuda14gwDQrPzSjQguSn@6l1imPL76O4Kvbr961QCCkFtawh8TXRztefbtjhe8PR6N1gq@v4i1W5WUpUa6pqal/i3Xycr3SqJ28r4hy9XW1Kd6XTs4qEbF5hmdD1w4fZMumZs4AL4QA@tEJldZwUlMguhhaQXFwfI5FwW54Go42o75v0LRE3@FwkOE86XFZQ7eo@vl@Ju7EiW1JNRHo5YW4FE9R0FAt@WsSrVf0JVznBm8HLUq48kDo16QZNb1DMenWk0TDDAdLkLctXreK91iuGoRH0obGoxSib0BZBJxvm6uL0OVDa2/H1ZakiBwVgkRzaUbM8@HOeaDYrXZue7VzQLBv6p5EEO1aGWg0BfDuxqzren84YtDm/YiBVvhHUw2jWkKUMyO6/OoJBbkgrOMS2XCLZkH4NEwGvf3DWVIk1VoYp2rSrqwosKzdu548ZIrq56jBQeriMSrx1soENu@bwkfuaHXI8mv7l5wNLkCnt@j/TX8XiT2Lt@665CL@@N5ac6p/FyDzjuGOXQojm0L1tFx5VznFK2nEPyofP9TqZTQJN6Jbg7z4PTKEvic2mVA93easG1hVBS5G2SjmrronCuSYSzFyuzArcCTIWEY78SI4amTwHPwCD/Lm5dBJsTqIp2WCzBnJMDVWYDCbiNV1no6ZuUMI7vkqP1AmzbsmL1fH6ylW6i4fWDcfUxfz0z@07e019R/a/rO4@mSZZWORtFchRvxnuUaI9tdLfYjQALNugO6e5CvDZ/6@Ayj@/UaQrF/fOH7K6PRHDeLLvwbR/7@L2QMrP4@rPHpg5Z2YyvOHtrwbV/mhLb9Yy7i@qXOVey0Rtdh9ATtLu9tfK9KftCIpu@ddi1L8oKHd769h@zOHjSyvXz5wZIj8a@T@zJFjW/CXDx1aQ/8auT9z5Mge/W0SHBoiI4NIBtIofqi6R7ELt8PuFWjXJADhj3eJkGjRjKAQWDOd1APIZD60MVQnv04h/Fpd72sZjZ120OotzdZCeaxLxiq01/U67L3xvnQi3tbK1eM4D44VAnnOHzalt0nR98kWWHLxI3nfxBnNZh02LT@YqiIWCDoJ@mOO4f2xkwz9klqqeJtsw7L9GFdr9pf165kP8H2Wnrs3Mxfjzz28YUmFeI/tucaBvh2lVMZLlU9qZ3UY2HrjCyZ6z/19BtadrqUjmzi/hvuv2UFfrYFRTvIXV57U0Z7JUogZfN5Kxjtoa6ZOiqXpj1w7QI3eYpJ7fr1i@g23kf6WNtIPa2PzW9rYfFgb2W9pI5uNa2TNslSuHJ69FlnReFP7EF@GvniXeEEU3u7UnTnOZN0SFl7DoM7vw@uxlvM/zQoY2SH80fBnR6TSvfZ7uRx9AunEv8dCX4S0weHh49EZTlQK5QcND12A9geOz5fsF3FjxFThY4rflJ5rbPGntdM0GeBDhni@w973bNVN8p6HSQKlVd5zr2Zd/TyFUtPiGPGXIDNtaiVy6s4dDG9TCjvQcogPxnmpfA8U@ipUJlG@GySeb9kxdQsGPLaRwA/3WxrxvVxX2gktTEo8Ie48n8RvJvF9j10sA2/n1ooDcLuVRIySbcWQRIhYMBs6oHQ6jVU@J5lRk4XPtyATEih4vF2PR4wHcCyusV7PKyXX@zKv8n3QvLmWoCvjHAsvEnLiA191nTbXxI/5E0HmaA6xhzxHossj9IskCnceuS1CqZzDtUXS0iN51pKTj9MCWdMSC1iC8N@4Bf/BLuOxE@FhAxzvGK5dU0aXCRtr5xEt9yN1uLoRM5diYYSrxUlsePILBI@n9prNUePrlWBE4gipBfAZ@8px4l2cT1Xj2PqeU//I@tBXikUwsfH03J/ayeTtmrWB5xjV9y9PQKpYQHQzLk5Rx@1gHWqEBGk7nqQL6JnrS2IhLV4pZa6dvlPKOhdAXz@35E48RaqcuhPnK0jIf@8lYgwHhiew729ir9hINKWMj7ZJrEiTWEEBRP4ZN2UnJFS/lafD7LoOHdYRS6JeKZVFo1kXx2enR6J62mjii9oxfTipnlZiTnWW8cOib3@K4C1F7XaQ@vHBK28YEG@I/0qrMGnziuBy7KWnGzG7P/b3cPk9c4xoH4rWiqMsipfxhFUjVLifBvEVWwC7HSjiw/adgIacE@PfgAviqXE3X9yrDWgawcQV3hUm9cLNxFmADuIlzYeuUa3Cc16WcK/@jXZKTUCI3SnXix0xi1GctLzGnqeuxPiCgWMS0n3wMbKFVDPVLRnG2nlHBfJr7H6Bm5NcEKIeTqHhiehvpUNYdUtHzUpZvK0039TKDf9TxJkX43SjUbqroW9aCK4ZCc5PXjiDq0k0xpRC3ya9B0Lm2NnYsNYM5WqKD3nNdEcu0GgFI7r9Pbk2Wu@odHJSOjypSNJEA/YWTlfqsZjztzO155fRHrAaqyJu/WKw28@SkewvL5NR9HQIkW7RYETehXRrWS9SBAltGvdFnnO8OCDtx2vLpoLEOFq5DNMhSG1jGphZ1DCQC0S6K9J5PSD9sRZ1TNfpyLTp/NrC9EgT54ammu0npTX@JwRyPzC8MiejK3NxwZU5iq1kp34Kid4LYiwTB89zOzIe/L64cCaxTHUUDvIXU3e0HIxceIYHoHi251xnJ1ejkYFbfm/Y74cHQX8@@G4bb8R0upeuAGz@Pw)

I run it outside of SerenityOS (in Ubuntu 22.04).
Build: `Meta/serenity.sh build lagom Shell`
Run: `Build/lagom/bin/Shell polyglot 2> /dev/null`

SerenityOS Shell supports escaping a newline with `\` inside a comment, unlike any other shells, so it skips lines 23 and 25 and ends up executing fish code.
It is separated from fish using the same thing, escaping a newline inside a comment:

```sh
#...\
echo 353;exit
echo 451;exit;'...
```

(fish skips the code of other shells for a different reason: it recognizes `\'` inside `''` strings)
It is necessary for both fish and SerenityOS Shell to hide a lot of stuff after `exit` inside `''` strings to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: Love that you're still adding to this after all these years. I pop in every handful of months to see where it's at, and I'm always impressed at how many languages are included.

Answer (score 4):

## 82. Brain-Flueue, 2280 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'@*99.?.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>\';    a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
<3>
<>{
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#ssss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004290 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2365 bytes)

### Rundown

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLc9tIkj4bsf9gLmWQbQAk8SJFvfiQZFuadXd7pLVke6JJWoZAUIQFAmwAFCnLdOx1N/Yw97nscf7HXPdXzB/p/bIKfEikZHfEbMSCFlCoyqrKV2VmZcEXTtL/7bccXewkCm4ugyhlqZekrBv7115ssOc3bN/xk2q5IkkcKo66I9cPL1na95gfDkcp6/mBl0iuk7ImG2ajGFRgORZ7TleASb0oZtSFDa4C5jN3OGQXgdM3XBb4gD2ytgGfRAOCSb14GHu4Jyz0vC5Lhp7r93yXz8W8SeqFiR@FicF894qN/SBgXS9AhwUCbgmDsVGyVCWmM6RuJDFc7vAeuvO3vAeY0JuR7A2dmJMcsSGnf0b5OHaGQyAp5dgpEE/9gZcwP1US5jmJT3xEl8QLu5xbwzmHI@aEy1Sya99hDvAdxXzsxItTkGfwcVnfiz0M6dDkl7EzYOo49lOwgJh5wE48J2ZnsedpmAVC8BLXGQKPO1NisohmSIkQgwurXlcOj48UCE30MJxhKuXiytm//Sg5zGiw/HkNfw1ZrkmHf3rJbvNtKgMLDAbBDmPV0VjjK0vMdtvD38S@MC/jqYRRJXAlYGY0TE2M7MQp0FuU9OuyMQyWpmX1e5JYUiQB1YUs2KuQvStxutxRHHvAYsFS5wokB1F4CW6C1HgUEjdCtmlBAG4UdpMS867BsygUEorGnL9nfR8iS0ggzgXY47jEebEIODuxDKB5GT9n8yZRMOJw6JmkpH7gCbrSiK967B3rOX5AXdBOQwmsYy8ZBSn1GYVdkvvAD72uwWZouFGXgAbRNaZzMCivwLoZLK02jhSAIYaIk0pN//jLX7uXlxjnwHWjuJsp6zvWjdzRAAg7HFkHikjqGoVOwNECXIlmF90xwbUT@F0npenDm2wKjgSfdRyNgi6LMGE89rGw@s41FmOv57mpJ1Q8GqXAscQGzpWwEb7QWxA@cC4gWD4Bn5uTrbP9F5CS6wmF0QejtLfN9OEhUxLzg7q3q@49bXvATTO0Qt40L2vQNqPAq/CmPKY47w4W8iTtOfMjWkXBsD@CzUBLmAxhTWJipuuAnISMSgq7V2IXnNHcEkHR@RIde0rssQus6xlhXEeEDlB/ndZtNsJCpjO4uyrmdZc0DNoJJUuTFSMRRGNMzHEj4wmdDmly59LBVGlG0IEgSMzIa@6SdhVC02m0C49t6xc@pEN6AFOTCWOJRoBXygIGownpLS2KgXODUVxhoheSZH4PQh5Ab@Mb5nq0GLAqPGHnaJIRV4zEhx5FPWbp5Wr1G8JPY/NA/8V09M/mozIm4u@J@YD1vDELnPBy5FxCkaMQXRzX9YZptoJASZJijdw3g7xSz2y6kfSl/P79ublty6z90hxkfYT0MgvtkNqDUQOwWg@wypkTX/KVyLp@jPUS3NyfHQDX9yaXPxLIHQQ@yg@gMHNMUDJv4rmjFMsNijzu@24fukvYhWLBCut4f3pULc8Ok6P35lMTMnbzWVkyzHkVofHgEDpJdHUcWH0aqnmnggt/ueLxkZ1ksGbgaI4iLNRSrWE6BnQvYxq8@SlFEjB/M9fNV9Y8vJjzEwz@kRxT7P06gsCgz/5lSCBOOHf7S5bRT0IFrsJPfHCdHDjp@tmrY/IH7z0Rw4DvwpctG/MIEQ26Zw6aGmZCkDy3HzE9ZEqGgypzf/oJaJlJ7PKCvhREyJoBPqnEL940G@iTiM3uO1TWXIXjUyol1pLlTgk@LEigQuEoCPAyCvkSUz3tFrrmekliYMGAtwZFI8BOLnra9C5g2o@jMfOmWk1ZN93vFMiL0YU/@X8oEZfwEndQtSQGXvU9clgBnAlCljPWrUBw3r2IBmTn2XtOMeH7PIZv6MEfSMObtA9Lp7tMdhrR0ANKdyyJAjwRnKtajQd0imJ8ivxQvVWePn2q7CpNpYTSHkp1Ku1RqYjSHi/pvERwBpV4jxIvUWuL96C6jjJtzUaeaB0S7YSi1s/@UHVau7uVTslp2dmzTE8NzgS@A9A6PTCOojUaVNQ0uTkGocZFTxLkn0E4PyPkYz/75Il7CBAXGwdpPllbkgUzKndtqbxoKYtY9Z05APuM4c36KEJeHop3eO2HVxHpqDmYlc4tw67eGQL7ndWePT/p89sd0BW0Vlt472Rw0eO3NQC7WRiAmIL2SMQXbsooEokiaP6Ygw2iMBKogF9@6Jhv@MOA91iHz10jfQeZ5x7W/KWn71TMCz80L7zeQ5BHz5@/4jC9iwv/ISAwhfCePdeAxaOLdTxDbNZfceLsDtfPRnEa6F0zpaf3P//eBfdXZdN3bhJE81fzwjmYRnLSew@KKutKL/y2XqyfRgF2et8Yw3UogneCeWH9WLvsjQfdh1hDvsEDpkEAewKWwc6tKjfWRTDqerPn@kE5D@/GAqJ36A90aPamYXEB4pXiG259HhjlXkAjhqGNTxxETtcUW1HfW0hU8N6bOJdReGMueTYjvvgOVGcxB1vsPdP@KB2JO204vyU7f0h/jy3IDNKqHjy3D7PHA/BAYvMh3RXLhky1fhQ4V@YFFc97KK4nVRAT@5fY3c6eD4G9Px06rmeOE3o8aD/CUTLkguSlh8AQPcaBuD8E4ocuPGu4KDwECBIDfvs9WseVwHUCqF5FKB7le/QlHvn3uBo4Fzfkz/q/X4Fo1stikemwIQ23WLQqTI8WG7JFZmk4fLi/62b9d3bW9xZJKD6AG2Hv7H3LKcGz@AOwoNxdKj6oJH6kL/Z/idAsigfWGSPn2kF8EDgJdCXNOO5dQ0L89pjukstwR4ETL0qPae49pGZ78Ie2cYueQ9@N4NyFqtJL4K/V1pDivvsx0mIYSjDy26IrvWVm9CXCIPLEXx@1pZGb0u7pATX6DvMkNi60NVzSCyN6iGluNKa/B1dwP7r2xH29W/q8FqvvMD96wFUCwfdq9677LW197ycwPritN4tXa7FK3WBt/S57HUUxdq4JKxvWo@JZq8ynxivjZ@PYOGWnfhAlj/ID@/YkEff1qrwAvYh9J9Rd0uHl8vpuaxHjLo4d8PsDAnaCyyjY3L40Hdwe1IJR3CNrnz2/18jNjZRtf9NIzcOaKLSz54Mm/gr/vqUglBWBTfcpvpkX1yvLNyxathl4mEzsAKjnehKPrO25jsWJt1a5MHcGcxC7/bFz86gKfsufPMTsmT/ZpSw@D6UfReab02w8Pk33@@zVyrBbjw97R8g/BR4M9hXdV0TLypb9O3vYlvX91qsXjLzRmqXAt4xv@LnAPFGXlLLjDNT5cZa@TuYnRLlXoRt7PG03S0SwHCUTRwO4vDSKDcbhVNUpFjVNEp3IeF6GAJtB8Sw9JUrFAUDC4MVSDovNbqvF8reTXWvXnrIGk3dl1umIUXnK7nAy5On1N6JrK@90GnlF15W80g53maVwUC@ABq8Fde7A9Xz@EHguSGehM@C5WSrPKK2JBDBcDGX9@07YRaz/NvR5jsWNYpHGFLlyvq/6@9@62WHIpQciB37iBGAEHd9FA68fjffEvNnsB8OhQ4cpNAZCzEBkYfQXBywZ@6nbF2cg8IBvj862swR2dpyIlxMK8pewEEJFUw84OKkQmsCmG3liOWUTz3vNiEJYMRqEbOx3035iwFeErscT5LOkLTCJCSxM44iWY4m9Yl2P4l2eRPo0gmyDKLriuSvC5O9/E2l7NPqkQlSeTc/PkZZmZNBpm@fKXTcaAevZIJ@9OMpAVGIygqMROHIDY@CJeo25fYefJ0AT9Vk2naYRGfUXB6dMP2QKnYJScr3m99T8wZs/vmtZncZXNjCxBTYpn8f5Jv@gb9mJXGIzkNqU9Gq52ULzolVhcn4iZ2TRiRs/YJorlVhNTKUyF9csOz7gh3Vc77wxz47zI5CQYj86BQsTrA@8anxosWgaeRV754GfMv00ZVU6KvbAEpTE8R6jw1fK9FKX/IR9YX3SFd1ldtXCm2BIQIcLg8YiY7GcMjJfehcjvrW6LhvlSoOTkz9v1Ju8FHvdiI6fWh/a446ZzLjSbk9@sMoTsC2KAf7MpJVz@KeXt3mjaX35ksBpyPJUqfGUHi3v/O3Jq5PD07ODs7enYONUUJk7iuKBszARpATDAD69HwX8PA/8iH0v@bbZeMLthvQkA1RVlndYHTaUwUI9mRuWjK2yLudFUbRxSzJvu9eYmY@ezzJTx064tDPBKsmymSvNFICYhzU5gl2dIQ/FuV1jrjg5MmuAIB0EcfA5wvO3dYTdbeXwguF79A6mZ2QsQ3FSF1DrgYhWAZzhLWAEkmuJmP6TMB/Cj3wbc4L6FuYAlr41@9LERwevfn775nB17qVpM5gVkLmGLH1AcThBFAY72OMaTsd0M72JsmPWmWGA3e@L3L8TLExbMk/jkyb1yDAHWNu0KHiSI6HFzciOGOwgSGBIu11YhoublAwLLKrI3M/T93IODDDmfq7EZIlgk8bqcRsMxxixsvtRdM5zOD5ysu7Euu2Z//jLX8UpdTtF@T@ycg/l/xLlDyYxaPVYU@A4Zw2x5d2rE5bAWwnCB85kiSZyGOSQ/BCxjj8AB685QwhcILugdzGO2noHfkIIYCZZPjJ2fD4v7qj9NB3umib5d2w9egZPfXoTyAG20kCwbv46oo8GYJ/Nzermhm0CSf16NiA/i7qkPJwYUNN2oULStT9sfLxwWb1eZ3LiOoHX2KwJRpp550NF/jhHNA9YSYQCLYY@6LLogbZm1k3NO0Vbo660ChVbYZ0avLyQCxyFygsA0ag6zPghwxNFGavoWMubpNyo3sxCHMQXYcQGxCf@6chsIB0DibE1WVrRXeCLFp5s8@/ElsayGOT3BMZTc7vyOtVh0JD/XqM5Icr/KcqttqV/7az77GGuOwerXzeo979NIFrY/mkYUf71CLgytWyWK6a9qS2tEzkbCtjSqviCIbEOsK5cz/8UDZODF4evfjw@OV05neeQyn0whSnNerGtG6VWZ15Q7un8jKXPj8zT18@PZoxcxipruo/VusHvI/bAZO9FdnN1Kt6wMpFtfe/Aiy3KWkIWG5glwBci87Iyq6rdTluderMd5lam/7Lu05mcUaCvZVBqJ/zDGYWtMTCvZjnbs@gK6vHINwF6ShD@5@WvA2YZXzp6LzfNrndt0lmxZCxywXJerd/BVhPfLwgezKaHnchq8tgZNtliLldaSaMtIyIyGdEckzs958wmmo/Fzo5//uOECOpj3xXQCTeuYv/Hv1XBDuBVutg0YCOCBeXzvdEN3wdgmc/TUl2fZyyd@CajYN5y6g18/WyGDy36xYEsjFAUp9h@JP3Av6g5jdaEzY8rHzurNZJh4KcqHZJODNpfgRpVIwLseuDRGWt9p5Md6LLZuWuRH92ejMCvk2jIFnval96s9AbbGvZyhMGhAR77cTQAXI8/3nhk4T32p0hHZ/BRmSHRwixqRoMx6FYxu9H3Jl3/El5C1UowKD/Y9uLQ19GK2IsqsKGCVX@kXNsyY37XQfUSx5yWY/hh15uoyljRdjvEHdQr4/fXiiav6AA/Lc@Ozrv3j81na99Js0U4P3JeXjizgAWTZwdWcCL0MSN9poCNgg@d3v/JC0OojAq0B1AQ5oxAZ6yVZl/UlubfPy3ZhX/Nzr/ue4lD5TaI4AvzZo1vSWpTOISPbdZO2712SF6hdmP@wTTM2q2aDxo3Jhy51lTz/YZdrBSKxXxYUPMhubJnz2gnM83DU54bsiFPAKTnA60GfsKzNvJhLe/U1Xy3US7wHngtFrVbdPiamMZt3pma@WdwTCXUxEI71HyikTgsw7CnwI8klDdLA2d4q8pMntBnZDR93i8WCQcjf04IfDXbp0VuptqnJt871bIAybwczNT4jjL89lvO3kSsPlWj4l658nRfZ7JZaL@8riktp1c2fu2cXJ2c/Flrq0ruxbFsb8i1ginlzIL1Zcs0P378iJiBaS1d6bTU5tZWoVba3C6U9ku2UqrlWGBbtq2p5bLW3ghP2ZPakydPVPtEUaoV5fQDffuw9xQ//g/X/JXuT3lNVs1BVq@nGlN/nUi55hPoSWXz6f6Tj1JOyp03i7gMfi8Wd3f3dV2f4M8o7km5j3XA1DvTabHeqteNZnPS1DvNlpS7lXKTqZQry8SAgpRrTOpv@ACtl9lIxV9/xq2ud1rDk58PD04PS@W6nisfHbwolU/fPs/ZeKsuXqmxQq9vDg9eHr89K5VFrz@@enf49gT1vu8Pk2432TjePN7vRv1Oc3@/aADRfaPZAUaTH4rNYiNNU/bLecFwYin3sjl5a@p1YPGzlHvDYfW2BugvUq6Va6l75b2yFVjXln1lX72Ojhf/jo9R70@sT1Fs9a2@3bVte2J5b60b62ZiDaJju4uih581QNG3ehPr0gqt0LbvjPPwv8Fx9Po4wlARuqUTK6VRrR6el8fHrzFYDxN/ws@3LMJvYl3jnxXY/PpwbmmWhA1hp7o5LG/@2uKmpbrTaXkTP@3IrKS0W0qnljOTdtsUuiyXoY7UPJ2en788ODs4PzdphzSp54v7RX0fV6NZrGePvVy3SRwz6pKijt@/f09/78fXY1HiBVH3ft64/MILuK4f6Hu3oKpGYfW3be8YRRSK@61q53aqMfyetJWaIghSVQ8uU5Xt9qTcY2WZe6Id2AG7gmhf3axqzeZmFe@b25quWtS6oX2w6/WsqaxFsaxM5ChW2O1U/NTbaV3ll0Y/TaPK7N7UVDRrVbxNbtU6flSFGup0O21SkYNNRQl3jAD6KLD/P/oXJdiFMiU3zZGhD9lGVcO2wdM2NtXt4k72azwF5qpcUSogSFYcZb@ws2PsrWM5/ZScNFOQhp0jDkk5o/ZGtsuyQgpToxxZFHhGgOi9siPJuCQF4aFSo80lbLiapafa7YllweLVLhr525wzrUmSPJUFWHYRq5UaT1fKt3LeiVt2BzD524sp@TdcBVvjzqm6UasVNkR5a7tWQ0Mha7HQkhXR4CWOyxUdNpUPD6o1qXHhXfqhVK80pXrzVoI3vgADx2zLQrQVBE7Mol7vqahHWIH9mAe36gUBbWwpqh5HcdAdI9J7KuUSD9fgxPFGnjcejcbe/HrhJ7vOp0@IFodk@hEMWJJBjrtc3tmubu9Uytul7Z3tjaq9Wa2W7HLJ3tre2rFKsP3b9uZ2dccubW/sVDY2NnbQWt3ZknJe2PV7pgkja8sy4wWEnPQVTZ2@N4qMfpNJua7Xo1zmk0Dtak9y3XnFaJvJle221bZkib4vYyoEckv2QmUJgsOop1qlEVZIdW@0LW9uybsFPOU9uYIiC1RmKRChrLRlWWvtdPbkrSqG2oU70pVn9h6Tt3bkXXlrC5VabQrsZlTP8WawIobB8KfrErUL16rKW1izSg1gNdHlX5b6xFe7SerEtA3h4IjSN3dkqgZIvVm9KOyWbL20LwZjm7aUm0pdOp/f2KmRe5rWm1JeIYqVipTTK9FGlMvn8/BmZ025Ih8bdTPzU02T@6k2@S3yEYbUwByk1jk5dzNZutoCnKbKJV@iqv01/LGW2x0qlQ2l0m7khFmyt7Rcs7xlJM5NriPqmLqxpTG8cSUt27nemF9za7liO5dKa97H1wPuZYHG9h@6l5d@@Q@vP37BTktRsGLsza96Xfyr4/biWOAlb1ZlLZfg@nD@4Ryev8rkclVmrGgy7NfMP5ehozs7m9ubOek303xsp4bWeaDZ8xCDjQbrIs2D2H/tUGosnEebKLweYUsy12FGSkwxfL95t44r9p0q/r@HUCcRXiRZlQpOfOmWeL6OFeirr1ZHY7ezXK9KrZRu1ObZydhLR3HIrJrIItMQfm1exCy0KliDAHgyEQ5E9Rt2jfl1GgxPxKPZDHTNehQbVKR9EMfC72g1aTntyjFpovcSLkv9i0UBPhVoCXrcQVeQLdrmr0BvQMdTrpr11u4BtKwOYJS2pWRkfg8Z2HCo8xFK7HeTca8/Qm9tRhNHYdGY1S9EMZUKaWlQk4jswrAm/aS62i1tCWpfB8@euR@GrUGnpg0aKT2LxUFtKl2pvgAppI1BQ7drQyBbS1vFot9pDLSf1CFHftCwAIy5aeREu51LOmxk4kq00udWqH8NO6WjVli0O6VRqfBL43PJaVilCf7AtlJQ@hXMm7FSTRufi2HNqeOPdid3ODFsJEWndjcbji5XatD43HI6DUurBehYLB6BGOCZtIJisaNh8gCNqx1rwbNnTjFoTmqBrmsE9aGyd9RKUegUG/S@qzr1yd7n1gj9d1U8G5gm0IA8@t2VAcYDfjXwWIhvgbrAcULoTYDeoNEo/LJX@KXQePr0c2uiDzolwf5dayF4Qn5CyC/riFr4ZVmxOEt4PKDKP/i7PxiFhMklaB@YXBou9RQYFn5By3CxGqb/Cw)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.

### Explanation

I've wanted to add Brain-Flueue for a bit, but its comment syntax post dates this question so I wasn't able to post until PPCG's policy on non-competing changed.  Brain-Flueue is Brain-Flak that uses Queues instead of Stacks.  This means that `(..)` pushes to the bottom instead of the top of the stack.  That's the only difference, they are otherwise identical.

Here's what the flaks see when they read the code.

```
[][][][]
((([]{})))((()<<()>>)()<<()>>){}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())
<>(){
}(((({[]}{}))))
<>
<>{
(){(()()[])}
()
}<>
```

Some of that is garbage that doesn't do anything at all, the relevant portion is:

```
((([]{})))((()<<()>>)()<<()>>){}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())
```

The first bit `((([]{})))((()<<()>>)()<<()>>){}{}{}{}` pushes 0 in flak, -1 in Classic and 2 in flueue.  Flak and Classic are differentiated by their use of `[]`, which is a -1 in classic but stack height in flak.  flueue ends up with a 2 on the stack because of its queue structure, but we don't care because we are going to destroy this value anyway.

The next portion is `({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)`.  For flak and classic this puts a 27 *under* the value on the stack, but for flueue it puts the value on *top* of the stack.

We then have `(({})){}`.  This does nothing in flak and classic which read this as duplicate the tos and throw a copy out, however flueue reads this as put two copies of the tos on the bottom of the stack and throw out the top of the stack.  This transforms the stack from `2 27` to `27 27`.

Next we have to if statement.  Since Flak still has a zero it will skip the if altogether, but since flueue and classic have non zero values on the top they will enter the if.

Inside the if we have `(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})`.  `(<()>)` puts a zero on top for both languages but `({})` rolls it to the bottom for flueue while doing nothing for classic.  Thus `({}<{}>({}){})` computes 54 for classic and 81 for flueue.

Once we exit the loop we toss the zero with `({}){}` add 1 to all of the totals with `({}())`.

Surprisingly I didn't break anything with the addition of Brain-Flueue.

Comment: The formatting is kinda broken...

Answer (score 4):

## 83. Objeck, 2332 bytes

````
#16  "}(o+?23!@- "/*\Dv;'[af2.q]PkPPX)\('#CO"14";*/
#/*0|7//```"`  )[-'][(>77*;,68*,@,1',;# l1011)(22)\4nS ␉;␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>␉
# 36!@␉`
#~
#_>++++.>++++++::@---x---.+?
#`<`
#<]}}+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++qL+++<-][pPLEASE,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACiiipsdds4O6O@doh]>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.ar
#D>xU/-<+++L
#R+.----\).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111x0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i0001k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0)0
[ "]56p26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'\['];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>+.--.<
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWw((.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*819.+.*.+@[5]{}) ) )␉\';';print((eval("1\x2f 2")and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0and 4)^1<<(65)>>62)or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>)}({}){}({}())wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'@*99.?.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*'#
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39
""""
'<>{\';   a=$(printf \\x00  );b=${#a};

"}"';           ((((';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in    *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;; *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;# (((('))))
=begin
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:ajjappp*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h> 
#define ␉l(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0\0"
main (  ){puts( sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37": l( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75\0":'??-'&1? "79":"77\0");}//*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
print'("72")';end;
#if 0␌
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end<>5b*:,1-,@
print 61
#}
disp 49;
#{
}<>
$'main'3
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O.</+++++++>/+++<-\>+++.---.
=end
"""#"#yxxxxxxxxxxxx\++++>/<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}
#s|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3\=#print(17)#>27.say#]#print (47) #]#echo 21#fwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''   16~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#sss^_^_#
#5 "25"  +/ *///X222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .004078 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 2417 bytes)

### Rundown

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03,
**38** in C99,
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11,
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11,
**76** in Trefunge-98,
**77** in C++14,
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17,
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck

### Verification

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##zVtLc9tIkj4bsf9gLmWQbQAk8SJFPfiSZFuedXe7pbX82GiSlkEQFGGBABsARcoyHXvdjT3MfS57nP8x1/0V80d6v6wCH5Io2R2xG7GkCBSqsqryVZlZWVDPSYa//56jDzuJgqvzIEpZ6iUp68f@pRcb7OkVO3D8pFquSBKHiqP@xPXDc5YOPeaH40nKBn7gJZLrpKzFxtkoBhVYjsWe0xdg0iCKGXVho4uA@cwdj1kvcIaGywIfsC@sXcAn0YhgUi8exx6uCQs9r8@Ssef6A9/lczFvlnph4kdhYjDfvWBTPwhY3wvQYYWAW8JgbJKsVYnpDKkfSQwfd3wL3eVT3gNM6C1I9sZOzEmO2JjTv6B8GjvjMZCUcuwUiKf@yEuYnyoJ85zEJz6iS@KFfc6t8ZLDEXPCdSrZpe8wB/hOYj524sUpyDP4uGzoxR6GdGjy89gZMXUa@ylYQMw8ZCeeE7M3sedpmAVC8BLXGQOPG1NisohmSIkQgwur0VCOjl8oEJroYTjjVMrFlTf/8qPkMKPJ8md1/JqyXJeOfnnOrvMdKgMLDAbBjmPV0VjzK0vMTsfDb2b3zPN4LmFUCVwJmBmNUxMjO3EK9FYl/bJsjIO1aVnjliTWFElA9SEL9jJk70qcLncSxx6wWLHUuQDJQRSeg5sgNZ6ExI2QbVsQgBuF/aTEvEvwLAqFhKIp5@@boQ@RJSQQpwf2OC5xXiwCzk4sA2hexs/FvEkUTDgceiYpqR94gq404ssBe8cGjh9QF7TTUALr2EsmQUp9JmGf5D7yQ69vsAUabtQnoFF0iekcDMorsG5Ga6uNIwVgiCHipFLTP/7y1/75OcY5dN0o7mfK@o71I3cyAsIOR9aBIpK6RqETcLQAV6LZRXdMcOkEft9JafrwKpuCI8FnnUaToM8iTBhPfSysoXOJxTgYeG7qCRWPJilwLLGRcyFshC/0FoSPnB4Eyyfgc3OydXbwDFJyPaEw@miSDnaZPj5iSmJ@UPdr6v7jjgfcNEMr5E3zvA5tMwq8Ck/KQ4rz7nAlT9KeN35EqygYDyewGWgJkzGsSUzMdB2Qk5BRSWH3SqzHGc0tERSdL9Gpp8Qe62FdLwjjOiJ0gPrrtG6zEVYyXcDdVDGvv6Zh0E4oWZrcMRJBNMXEHDcyntDpkCZ3zh1MlWYEHQqCxIy85iZpFyE0nUbreWxX7/mQDukBTE0mjDUaAV4pCxiMJqS3tihGzhVGcYWJXkmS@QMIeQS9ja@Y69FiwKrwhJ2jSSZcMRIfehQNmKWXq9VvCD@NzUP9V9PRP5sPypiIvyXmQzbwpixwwvOJcw5FjkJ0cVzXG6fZCgIlSYo1ctsM8ko9s@lGMpTyB7fn5rYts/Zrc5D1EdLLLLRDag9GjcBqPcAqZ058zlci6/sx1ktwdXt2AFzemlz@SCA3EPgo34PCwjFBybyZ505SLDco8nTou0PoLmEXigUrrOPt6VG1PjtMjj5YTk3I2K0nZckwl1WExr1D6CTRu@PA6tNQrRsVXPjrFQ@P7CSjDQNHSxRhodZqDdMxoHsZ0@DNTymSgPlbuG6@spbhxZKfYPCP5Jhi77cJBAZ99s9DAnHCpdtfs4x@EipwFX7ig@vkwEnX37w8Jn/w3hMxDPgufNm6MY8Q0aB75qCpYSEEyXOHEdNDpmQ4qDL3p5@AlpnELi/oa0GErBngk0r84k2LgT6J2Oy2Q2Wtu3B8SqXE2rLcLcGHBQlUKJwEAR4mIV9iqqddQ9dcL0kMLBjw1qBoBNjJRU@b3wRMh3E0Zd5cqyubpvuDAnk26fmz/4cScQkvcQVVa2LgVd8jhzuAC0HIcsa6OxCcd8@iEdl59p5TTPg@jeEbBvAH0vgqHcLS6S6TnWY09oDSDUuiAE8E56pW5wGdohifIj9Ur5XHjx8rNaWllFDaR6lBpX0qFVHa5yWdlwjOoBLvUeIlam3zHlTXVebtxcgzrUuinVHU@tkfq067Vqt0S07bzu5lumtwJvAdgNbphnEUrdmkoqbJrSkINXoDSZD/BsL5GSEf@9knTzxAgLjaOEjLyTqSLJhRuWlL5VVLWcSq78wR2GeMrzZHEfL6ULzDKz@8iEhHzdGidGYZdvXGENjv3O058JMhv9wAvYPW3RbeOxn1BvyyAaCWhQGIKWiPRHzhpowikSiC5k852CgKI4EK@OWHjvma3wx4j0343DTSN5B56mHNn3v6XsXs@aHZ8wb3Qb54@vQlhxn0ev59QGAK4b24bwCLJ71NPENsNrzjxNkNrr@ZxGmg982U7t5//1sf3L8rm6FzlSCav1gWzsA0kpM@uFdUWVd64JfNYv00CbDT@8YYrkMRvBMsC5vHqrHXHnQfYg35Bg@YBgHsCVgGO3dXubEugknfW9w3D8p5eDMWEL1Df6RDs7cNiwsQjxTfcOtzzyi3AhoxDG184iBy@qbYivreSqKC997MOY/CK3PNsxlx7ztQXcQcbLX3TIeTdCKutOH8luz8Mf0eWpAZpFU9fGofZbd74IHE9n26K5YNmWr9ReBcmD0qng1Q3EyqICb2z7G7XdzvA3t/OnZcz5wmdLvXfoSTZMwFyUv3gSF6jANxvQ/ED1141nBVuA8QJAb88ke0jiuB6wRQvYpQPMr36Gs88m9xNXB6V@TPhn9cgWjW82KR6bAhTbdYtCpMj1YbslVmaTy@v7/rZv339jb3FkkoPoAbYe/sfcspwbP4I7Cg3F8r3qskfqSv9n@J0CyKBzYZI@fSQXwQOAl0Jc047l1CQvzykO6Sy3AngROvSg9p7i2kFnvw@7Zxq55j343g3IWq0kPgb9TWkOK@2zHSahhKMPLLqis9ZWb0OcIg8sRfH7SlkZvS7ukeNfoO8yQ2LrQ1XNMLI7qPaW40pd@9K3gYXXriutktfd6I1XeYHz3gKoHg@273vvstbX3vJzA@uGw2ixcbsUrdYGN9jb2Kohg714SVDetB8WxU5lPjpfGzcWycslM/iJIH@YF9e5KI62ZVXoH2Yt8JdZd0eL28udtGxLiLY4f8eo@AneA8CrZ3z00Hl3u1YBIPyNpn9@81cksjZdvfNFLLsCYK7ex@r4m/wN@3FISyIrDpPsU3y@JmZfmGRcs2A/eTiR0A9dxM4gtrd6ljceJtVC7MncEcxu5w6lw9qILf8if3MXvhT2qUxeeh9IPIfHOarYen6X@fvboz7M7Dw94Q8k@BB4N9Qdc7omVly/6DPWzL@n7rNQgm3sTbaE2Oe588KM4D3OX7ytf88GCZzUtK2ZkH6vw4y3Eny2Ok3MvQjT2e21tkK1iOMo6TEfxiGsUG43Cq6hSLmiaJTmRhz0OALaB4Kp@yqeKUIGFwdSmHxY643Wb561nNqtlz1mRyTWbdrhiV5/WOZmOeg38turbzTreZV3RdySudsMYshYN6AdR8I6hzA27g85vAc0U6C50RT@BSeUFpXWSJ4YfoaGDohH1sCN6GPk/EuFEscp0ioc43X3//Wz87MTn3QOTIT5wAjKAzvmjkDaPpvpg3m/1wPHboxIXGQBwaiFSN/uyQJVM/dYfioARu8u2LN7tZljs7c8TDCe0E1rAQQkXTADg4qRCawKYfeUIrsomXvRZEIfaYjEI29fvpMDHgUELX41n0RWYXmMQEFqZxRFpVYi9Z36OgmGeaPk0g2yCKLniCizD5@99Ebh@NPqkQlRfT88OmtRkZFN/mCXXXjSbAejHIZy@OMhCVmIwIagKOXEGnPVGvMXfo8EMHaKK@SLnTNCLt/uzwlOlHTKGjUsrA1/2Bmj98/ed3bavb/MpGJvbJJiX9ON/kH/QdO5FLbAFSn5NerTdbaF61KkzOz@SMLDqW46dQS6USq4mpVObiWqTQR/xEj@udN@UpdH5OElKASEdlYYL1gUeNDy0WTTOvYoM98lOmn6asSufJHliCkjgDZHRCS@lg6pKfsS9sSLqiu8yuWngSDAnoBGLUXKU11vNK5nOvN@H7r8uyUa40OTn5s2ajxUux14/ojKr9oTPtmsmCK53O7AerPAPbohjgT0xaOUe/PL/OGy3ry5cEnkWW50qd5/1oeeevT16eHJ2@OXzz9hRsnAsqcy@ieOSsTAQpwTiA4x9GAT/0Az9i30u@bTYecbshPcoAVZXlHdaAoWWwUI@WhiVjq6zLeVEUbdySLNtuNWbmY@CzzNSxEy7tTLBKsm7mSgsFIOZhTU5gVxfIQ3GuN5grTo7MmiBIB0EcfInw8mkTYTdbObxg@D49g@kZGetQnNQV1GYgolUAZ3gLGIHkRiLm/0uYj@FHvo05QX0LcwBL35p9beIXhy9/fvv66O7ca9NmMHdAlhqy9pbF0QyhGuzggGs4neUt9CbKzmIXhgF2fygOCJxgZdqSZa6fNGlAhjnA2qZFwTMhCS1uRnbEYIdBAkPa78My9K5SMiywqCK9v8zxyzkwwFj6uRKTJYJNmnfP5GA4pgio3Y@ic57D8ZGTTcfaHc/8x1/@Ko6yOynK/56VByj/pyh/MIlBd88@BY5L1hBb3r08YQm8lSB85MzWaCKHQQ7JDxEQ@SNw8JIzhMAFsit6V@Oo7XfgJ4QAZpLlI2PH5/PirjpM03HNNMm/Y38yMHh@1JtBDrCVBiJ687cJvVkA@2xuV7e3bBNI6peLAfmB1Tkl68SAmlaDCkmX/rj5seeyRqPB5MR1Aq@5XReMNPPOh4r8cYloHrCSCAXaDH3QZdUDba2sm5p3irZGXWkVKrbCunV4eSEXOAqVFwCiUXWY8UOGJ4oyVtHZlzdLuVG9WoQ4iC/CiI2IT/z9ksVAOgYSY2uydEd3gS9aeEbOvxFbGutikN8TGM/f1eRNqsOgIf@1QXNClP9DlNsdS//a3fRuxFJ3Du@@AqHefoGBaGEHp2FESdoXwJWpZbNcMe1tbW2dyNlQwJZWxRcMiXWAdeV6/qdonBw@O3r54/HJ6Z0jfA6p3AZTmNJqFDu6UWp3lwXlls4vWPr0hXn66umLBSPXscqabmO1afDbiN0z2XuRAr07FW@4M5Ftfe/Aq33MRkJWu5w1wGciPXNnVlW7nre7jVYnzN2Z/sum92tyRoFeqUGpk/C3axS2wcC8XCR230QXUI8HXhzQU4LwP6@/QrBIC9P5fLll9r1Lkw6UJWOVMJbzauMGtpp4yUHwYDE97ERWk8f2scVWc7nSnVzbOiIi3REtMbnRc8lsovlY7Oz4O0JOiKA@9l0BnXDjKvZ//IUW7ABepqtNAzYitK/ke6Mrvg/AMl/mrvo@T2s68VVGwbLl1Bv5@psFPrToV6e2MEJRnGL7kQwDv1d3mu0ZW55pPnSgayTjwE9VOkmdGbS/AjWqRgTYjcCjg9jGXjc79WWLw9kiP989mYBfJ9GYrfa0z71F6TW2Nez5BINDAzz242QEuAG/vfbIwnvsl0hHZ/BRWSDRxixqRoMx6lcxuzH0Zn3/HF5C1UowKD/Y9upk2NGK2IsqsKGCVX@mhNw6Y/7QafYax5y2Y/hh35upylTRal3iDuqV6ftLRZPv6AA/Us/O1/u3z9YXa99Js0W4PJdeXziLgAWTZ6dacCL0xiO9y4CNgg@dPvjJC0OojAq0R1AQ5kxAZ6yVFq/dlpYvSa3ZhX/ODslue4kj5TqI4AvzZp1vSepzOISPHdZJO4NOSF6hfmX@yTTM@rWaD5pXJhy51lLzw6ZdrBSKxXxYUPMhubInT2gnM8/DU54ZsiHPAKTnA60OfsKzNvNhPe801Hy/WS7wHngsFrVrdPiamMZ13pmb@SdwTCXUxEI71HyikTgsw7DnwI8klDdLI2d8rcpMntG7ZjR93i8WCQcjf0YIfDU7p0VupjqnJt871bMAyTwfLdT4hjL8/nvO3kasPlej4n658vhAZ7JZ6Dy/rCttZ1A2fuueXJyc/KvWUZXcs2PZ3pLrBVPKmQXry45pfvz4ETED09q60m2rrZ2dQr20vVsoHZRspVTPscC2bFtTy2WtsxWeskf1R48eqfaJolQryukHekFi/zG@/A@f5SNdH/OarJqD3P081pj620zKtR5BTyrbjw8efZRyX6XcWauIj8GvxWKtdqDr@gw/o7gv5T42ANTozufFRrvRMFqtWUvvttpS7lrKzeZSriwTBwpSrjlrvOYDtJ9nIxV/@xmXht5tj09@Pjo8PSqVG3qu/OLwWal8@vZpzsZTdfVIjRV6fH10@Pz47ZtSWfT688t3R29PUO/7/jjp95Ot4@3jg3407LYODooGED0wWl1gNPuh2Co20zRlv54VDCeWcs9bs7em3gAWP0u51xxW72iA/iLl2rm2ul/eL1uBdWnZF/bFq@h49Xd8jHp/Zn2KYmtoDe2@bdszy3trXVlXM2sUHdt9FD18rRGKvjWYWedWaIW2fWOc@/9Gx9Gr4whDReiWzqyURrUGuJ8fH7/CYANM/Alf37IIv5l1iT8rsPnnw5mlWRJ2hN3q9ri8/Vub25bqXrftzfy0K7OS0mkr3XrOTDodUyizXIY@UvN8fnb2/PDN4dmZSVukWSNfPCjqB/g0W8VGdtvP9VvEMaMhKer0/fv39Hs/vZyKEi@IuvfLxvUHXsDn8p6@NwuqahTufnftPaOIQvGgXe1ezzWG76OOUlcEQarqwWeqst2ZlQesLHNXtAdDYFcQ7qvbVa3V2q7ieXtX01WLWre0D3ajkTWVtSiWlZkcxQq7nouvej1vqPyj0VfTqDK7tjQVzVoVT7NrtYEvVaGGOl3PW1TkYHNRwhUjgD6K7P@P/qIE21Cm5OY5svQh26pq2Dd42ta2ulvcy77Nx8BclStKBQTJiqMcFPb2jP1NLKevkpMWCtK0c8QhKWfUX8t2WVZIYeqUJIsCzwgQvlf2JBkfSWm0riEaWE8YcTXLT3U6M8uCyav3mvnrnDOvS5I8lznU4kOsVuo8Xylfy3knbttdwOSve3NycPgUbI17p@pWvV7YEuWd3XodDYWsxUJLVkSDlzguV3QYVT48qNakZs8790MJbrgHxk3ZjoUwKwicmEWDwWNRj3gCGzEP/tQLAtrRUjg9jeKgP0WI91jKJR4@oxPHm3jedDKZesvPMz@pOZ8@IUwck81HFGBJBnnscnlvt7q7Vynvlnb3dreq9na1WrLLJXtnd2fPKsHo79rbu9U9u7S7tVfZ2traQ2t1b0fKeWHfH5gmjKsty4wXEGvSOzYNehspMoYtJuX63oCSmI8Cta89yvWXFZNdJld2O1bHkiV6@4ypEMQ12QmVJYgKo4FqlSZYGdX9ya68vSPXCrjL@3IFRRaozFIgOlnpyLLW3uvuyztVDFWDH9KVJ/Y@k3f25Jq8s4NKrT4Hdguql3gzWA/DYPjpukTtwqeq8g7WqlIHWF10@ae1PvFFDVv/mPYfHBzh@faeTNUAabSqvUKtZOulAzEY27al3Fzq0@n91l6d3NK80ZLyClGsVKScXom2olw@n4cXe9OSK/Kx0TAz/9QyuX/qkL8i32BITcxB6pyTc1eztU9HgDe@5vh5Kzu5pjRT9kJq7RXmUp3aKX/xqN1l2tdf/OB6t6K3eMyG2HHO5oRmLvkSVe2v4Y/1XG2sVLaUSqeZE6bM3tFyrfKOkThXua6oY@rWjsbwxBW7bOcGU/5ZWtg79nattOF5ejninhlo7P6pf37ul//06uMXbM8UBdTY21/1hvhr4PLsWOAlb1dlLZckyYezD2c5KVdlcrkqM1Y0GfZ45r@Wod57e9u72znpd9N8aHeH1mVwOvAQt01Gm6LTw9h/5VA6LVxGqCi8mmAbs1R/RvpPcf@wdbOOr4kbVfzfklAnEV6kFCoVnPjcLfEcHyvQ62TtrsauF/lhlVopRaktM5qxl07ikFl1kXmmIfz6sohZaEGxJgHwBCR8juo37TrzGzQY7ohhsxnos@hRbFKR9k4cC7@r1aX1VC3HpIXea7is9S8WBfhcoCXocUd9QbZoWz4CvREdablq1lu7BdC2uoBROpaSkfk9ZGCToi5HKLE/TMat/gjXtQVNHIVVY1a/EsVcKqSlUV0isgvjuvST6mrXtI2ofx09eeJ@GLdH3bo2aqZ0LxZH9bl0ofoCpJA2R03dro@BbD1tF4t@tznSflLHHPlR0wIw5qaRE@16KemwmYkr0Uqf26H@NeyWXrTDot0tTUqFX5ufS07TKs3wA9tKQek3MG/BSjVtfi6GdaeBH@1obnBi3EyKTv1mBh1dLtSg@bntdJuWVg/QsVh8AWKAZ9IOisWuhskDNN7tWA@ePHGKQWtWD3RdI6gPlf0X7RSFbrFJzzXVacz2P7cn6F9TcW9imkAD8uh3UwYYD/jVwWMhvhXqAscZoTcDeqNms/DrfuHXQvPx48/tmT7qlgT7a9ZK8IT8jJBf1xG18Ou6YnGW8BBClX/waz8YhYTJJWgfmFwar/UUGBZ@Rct4tRrm/wM)

Languages currently not on TIO:

- Japt, 7 [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.3.0&code=&input=).
- Reng, 19 [online](http://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq).
- Deadfish~, 48 [local](http://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish).
- Moorhens, 60 [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch
- Morse, 73 [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/morse.c)
- Archway, 74 [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/archway/impl/archway.c)
- Trefunge-98, 76 [local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunge). Use `-v 98 -d 3` for Trefunge-98.
- Objeck, 83 [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)

### Explanation

Objeck is a language that I don't know much about, but from what I have seen it has boilerplate on the level of Java. It has a similar compilation model to java too. In Objeck from what I have seen everything is the method of some object, including printing.

Nearly the whole program is in a comment as far as Objeck is concerned, It uses `#` for line comments and `#~` and `~#` for block comments. A ~ was appended to the line previously only consisting of a # at the top of the program to open a block comment. This block comment extends over the length of nearly the whole program until about halfway along the 5th last line, where we see the meat of the code.

```
<~#class P{   function:Main(a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
```

The < at the beginning is for perl6 balance. The `~#` is the closure of the block comment. This code is similar in structure to a Java hello world. We declare a class called P (to help golf down the number of Alphuck loops); inside this class is out main function which takes a string array as a parameter,`~Nil` means this is a function that doesn't return a value. `83->Print();` is calling the Print method of the integer 83.

Everything after this line is commented out by line comments.

### Alphuck

A s was removed from near the incident jump tokens at the end of the programs because of the extra p from `Print()` in the Objeck code.

### Brain-Flak

Chance pointed out that the stack swapping we were doing for Brain-flak is redundant. `<3>` and `<>{` were removed and the brace replaced with one at the start of the Bash code.

### Incident, Prelude

Spaces were inserted to keep Incident and prelude happy

Answer (score 4):

## 138. [Braille](http://esolangs.org/wiki/braille), 6136 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTa Ta TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVk RcRcRcBkBkBk
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOxx4O6O@MoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l 111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++. _++++._#/+.--.<!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWWW/WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                    (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !           x
2   !    !          xx
1      !!           x x
1  x*               x x
53  +               x  xx
1  x*                x   xx
51  +          xxxxxxxx    xx
1  x*          x             x
34  +          x             x
15  +          x         ?   ?@             !
1   *          x        ?@    ?
1   !          x          +   *
1              x        ?  !  ?
1xxxxx!xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?x@x?
  x            x
             xxxxx
            x  x  x
            x  x  x
           x    xx
x          x
x         x
x         x
x        x
         x  x  xxxxx
        x   x x   x
        x   xx  xx
       x    x  x
       x       x
      x       x
      x   x   x
     x   xx  x
     x  x x  x
    x   x  xx
    x    x
  xx     x
 x      x
xxxxxxxx

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="23 12 30 1 "
"z c #0C8302""b c #B87A63""_ c #0000C0""d c #708FB7""e c #58007B""f c #FFC0FF""O c #FFFFFF""y c #FFFF00"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""m c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"r c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""T c #C3C3C8"
"A c #0040C0""B c #C00040""C c #C04000""G c #008000""E c #808000""F c #00C040"
"l c black""g c green""x c blue""o c magenta""c c cyan"
"fhtezAyAgBBBBCB_gxggxGc"
"fiTuggggggggggggggEFxGc"
"fjTuggggggggggggggggggc"
"fkTuxgggggggggggggggggc"
"fmyugxgggggggxOOOOOOOOr"
"fnbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"fqbyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz"
"flbyyyyyyyyyyOyOdOTTTTT"
"flggyyyyyyyygOOOOOOOOOO"
"fllllllllllllllllllllll"
"ffoOOOOOOOxxxxx_oOxx_fx"
"OOOOOOOOOOxxxxxOOOxxlxx";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z++,z++)?puts("124"):y  ();}//<*/
#1""/*/

>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxxcly"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~- COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002334 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6268 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLr731tGXLkqyn5cfxoShSokSRNElJlPbxRQYzSCfpxkxPOh2kk@7cezM9mADTH4IeDNCNDjDA9Nf@FedrMJj7D@6sKpJ62LL3PklkSyxWrVq1atWqVauqFos9zhj@7nd7@INqqrwYyKqJTMEwUV@XZoIeRtkF@sxJRjwSpSgMldEH04mgmMYhtYdYhCSFl/pwj0x1LCjSUtAhPoKQpqsDnZsgc8iZSDB4ThMMpE5NbWoiVdydLYpQYaKOpBDOOZGUAYCZgq7pgknSYwi1FJmb9Prci5T4iwI1HdINlBfkHyc/mohXJxNO6RsAmUAoX80WypkXGJIIXam6IWA8vGAYKo5MIWQVBP4FaBpAOV1Sy5nK2YsklkFnQDqnyYKFuJ5h6hxvSqqCk1iUlVXOFPqoUWk1als5CWtrutqf8rja5lCAZMwqUZIFg@KhSqdIcxoojANoD@kC17fBKFHVEc6CJmMZSYjXNNSTuWGYR7IEsEUmhQTMWbSEdHloIEubAAZDnQibdBhIEYA@QxN4SZR4UjoSLFNQDKiEEUYSP0ZzSZZRX5Ahw5okPgjI0NTYiLIJCFN9lULw4bUXFVjd7QsAowguEwQNmIuZoOK2AI64vJjrnKYBkcDMBhBuShMQKcn0GkjgDAkLLWQxBKVP@KetxFlFnLJZSzSTOMQBvVOd4DYEHbdRmOBFQ0EXACW3EijfXJdMYAFmbwbVBE5HTV0Q/NuivVUkFKbiEkxckTBpvuNjb6Fa9EIz2jnCnGZSe3q0eX1BcSh8gvYfj@B74vEcUYVKHn3Zv8dhW5KhqTXdx/nRyS@RQd/fC/C12B490J8pwEoBV2REq5pJcyENCAyZQCDN4SAOhWaRsCZvFIyOX7TFhnDZUH1oDVRSUDtIasZPdR331jVTuTFUWlaVAfATKqtPFcwPBSUYaAJehc4WRMIMuKYqdhupc8Lh5lCCRjNwk2z0D1vnEIaC1gHZczjqlmuo8pTAQU7DxAIIXIGsGGNJRG0kcpKMs0A6RmVTrQvGVDZxnqnSxy0POkXoh5FLBq/2MdBEnUFxHCAlEdCXJhs9kBAFwNAQKqkqTvrpX/5lfzAAPBmeV/W@I65t1Fd5oh05QiyoHIQFVlU4mZAFcEFcup0dCphxstQHnYD5sXCKIESQUufqVO4jFQrU5xJ0rSE3g@4oigKPtQimw1aoQTThxrbekGzJhYpPuB40LCmAlE2qHUKfc9BKvEDtEZkJTaammEIhrYC8Bv2979Oh79PHewGI84f9B/s0PTgCgQsfkCi4874nOe3MlsIzTM5QpT6lLcyhqkRQiEce/kTVBMXn3cLhDXr1ntcfxvrM5z@STviwKCl9nxdkPAvlev1H/Al/Jx0@HL3IvVkiYJljLLi3Cj7e76FA45A@MaMnnKSEtQVqh5zQRppqPGKO4@TwRjTmy8u4mR2xR8YTLJYqlg9QQ2FDFgTNx4RZP9YSGG5ntXHCroq@wOFU@FB6CHj3vIHNqhMMUNOtiuK@2pRUrLVkbTgFHQ1MUQwNtLeORZfnQHgMrMRNGNSDqEfEmmh@UCxEJc4Fry6gHuhRV4xIj7R7HM4fwnrSwbDuQS7cdocW@hv9GXQBdGnTeKWUZXUOBRPa8PAFGkTBhXMDaCLIbFcoY1fILpHEbFdtrIBewdh6AkqFehL0BdzrQLU7or9RRwCPRmwYwGb3lQ0VNOEWgIW3h8R1v0GSCF1qAlpCXyBewKoHdJBgjyu4kCnphgaYM9iwYUKReHy7q73qaaZOZ0K3oKuX9LsdCld@s09hfYNEYY5kThlMuQG2qBTIwvG8oJmOvoKaGCZopJfDDokMOWNo2BhS@59flk3GEmd03SgD63q79ZwRkcNKxrGpQjLoVMQ5ViHqSzpoJ3nxsnQAmL0o3PMDBtki4AfPGyS4hgAImWAJ/NQE5QaCPB9K/BBkF1On2OrRHoteFg9Rm6WDgg@Jq6IxMezpdxEqTK@iMBlvogjhFn2NB8ZYjOp0K4I0/mbE@5g5Y7IDsboiEcaDjdgwzYVB9r6Cc6Iq6g6kwMgVWgyynWK3AxhkDWwMwvjlWl@ks64sxFUTQZuB9oCeD/I3NE3NOIThQjKH014YJIVu6ouSWVWwsNCmvpBM1Q73ZLUH6tmA/km7JdD8tCdZLypE4lZtODKoGdhhooFOYAB/moLU@byiAYqTxOcw8EaShyhwgsL@9QAgAQoDo3yiQVRyEZRKY6HwPk@YdKUwdDpPEHlwx/X4IYBzrfiSUydYC6EOsQ@wwZfVQXOJoK0c3U9UP7dzxFuNAcS883rDI1VSfF@8Hz9@9B56T0HDf/z4CULHOPQJhwIQ@kRCIRLCcGEcIjmCJIRT70gOHPfgfb5zMVv@B9xsFh6dlpLm4@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@vkgseLXfRsj3xbxPQEcQpTR7onKTj8FbBQOkUgxV5PegsU@IJJd687wPRpbxfbQLiGr4wjtMV4c6qbstB3rv/t9/vQAK@bZ8gtYMrDj1eBR@AbbqqQ@GZrOVnxDfnZ3bIEZjSVJY6wgYS@hpLn8LSUk1eB3aixakah0JDToXEXbuOCcOIfGGbfkTObcl2Qp33Bve4uhLB42wSzcyvShNQIrtieJOPpG9lfGJB2fjyt10EJ9QkWe7lFEtatbbeLYHEDqBy9oZFAU34Dna6dh9brK2DQmFP7Fy@pfK1dJQ1/d3PlcFvImDjXYwWYjnI96Q0@YjISb0m23WGwCRISZW5sBx9xcHdl7ero0mAAppdzfQsM7GyYCmkcL9BzcnlTyeCRwG4MHHoHny7bv2@BuAvEq8BbgFBNmfz8HMEjosBD78Ck4kXN0AaLpBdMlbneAptpw58vQbhAMtKCgjnhAwEmigfd1Sx4vXyqaW/nx1YCyZ9O785tr7QSBLwqioLwtV4LI4804eRQpL8RfFMJu2btOrQDdMTNODB4Zc4AATEdNgszaBby857Q4sGEn8qcvg69I7JrctzFjrfmy@s8msSrsuRIpnvzljZ8OdNYo8Fr6eRnnRXfveZvH4x7PFCHVqHdHVrlTTxnfUOOvkFB2dNFPCHfEIyw@hbveHWOv2/23qE6E@zf3YPWcidV36B@QjKRDJgwvs7e578mrnjxk/zs5uJ4J1UmL@@MP0RXqqoPBcVAkTCDTRyFrNjDkC3L9vy1Waq@LdOGJKsGapDf93gBkwLDsH93S/Mm2yROCfFDu4@twruz7SSKDHAoQ37faFxOHqhyIjWgOfh5UwKmuoi1vHP9Vg230lAs@1UNtTJ4VIV1rm@q9jH8f004yFqsjpcoNoLv2FG71JkztX27gjAnwOuOuytXZFIkZ5i2Z3JvNYDOD@fcwr3@A0aPt7jrjh7agpjLYM/hDOkUBEzdNqH/IaXF3i@t/2066hXa5NcqsdG4Y1kAjU1@XzUpijDsz8zBMsy3ayxRngpTYacGqfZGAojNe7rj24linGrsO2sfNDAPb9OuoJbOZPCbqMbjOb57V@FwsgSd/KvWzE5Vo4GNreHJcw0CNRx4nXGgTLWtxt3gXX2q1N/n3FBze7ba3yISp/xcjZT6us20ZYYbAvm@ZbIXJipMedUJ2BDKN7S/g5QsE9m/W4hJzBrzSMIrVvq7eA/Rai0T7FewR6BVpbERwste36Z4Im/N1QlwOg2zMUUwF/j3LW7vUqQ9VZV/TuuAPu1L2EwD4xP7K3ytlV7ZPs6yNlqvShh4haMnvrUeYY81zsQRuIcnyW82dA2qZJLB4Vta@dU64Duj1saq4NfmjzBik0UfQ@fd8Fv01nHnZsOpcPJdgt0VMdoNvIcsHY5@i32kuUYvWXTFC7X20uza4WLvhf7RFsApqR8y@KEwEcjtOxY/1x9NDffyJpCl4u@O5DBNlk3fyKdJ0OEV/Lu1DLxhEpmqIhi0yekDAc9VZIEDa9SOfUvJuquxO5lbmnADofhVyVovOeANT16XtoK7Fx8O7T0IHrJ9RY3Y00BVGQsLw73uNpYXPLTndPIutl2dnMcrm1/t1WF65wr0V2w@ZagOlaEw1EnPWN291TdAIk3bJeu9SgD9Q84Y4x1eRyFpZhmFntDGbG9obPJZVmX5W/iMVaOtKFV19/JrAftY9SHrz8K74HqQ4Fy@ulIHIzhhFxnK3@pFQ2EKA5WhmqomhMjdW6AyWeqR31jmOUQdSdD732QivdxGeM9yBxzu9TWYs7VEXJFWu9VG0PGhgjhJdzxmjJVb2l5J4XWB7F27e5loD@@oTydTmTNVPYwInM/HBQJ@P2VnwnPZgQJgLhRxDMLeArbPkYFkyTAJrCSiuzu0/8U6ZA7ZZ3SCPIce9PBgYyX71gVLIx49dTvr3T73cLLvDYW8@9575RAxXgIqyDC12AnKbcGJErnYdK6rjhRuQhwUcNit6ZHtBQEzfuxoNOSUPrC1BWMjWQdRdXsv33YYaeLF7//6N33H/wqUoYEmkgGm5EDBPoPqRBiq8092uU7pGU3jsP8WxjEf4tVdXHool0HGXDJB@RO3K3WOWsVmyvHicLwa4aaGVeAGFXaj4mEZ@xaZdqPZ1PRVwRY0p@BVLrdSvCpPJwqaS31zaIRh@q7wAvESWe3rQQiDKaaOe18/iEqoL@Clxz4mjAw9sqqOyYYlpuS//o3tuwKJEhYhHHaLJ65rGyUiPJwShxGeV6dAtYtkKeiqA@LDTAb1N8VWHXQTwY73I37IEacakMSQ61KCi7HdSnKZBgoVkBe7XuKN6iNJ9O1n6mftO@bh5JdoQgv/7fdp/xeHb55fhJKs4QkiF@ToGcvVZjIDyetUL/LsWx6nWtjJj/i0rYTKcej14TBpLtdFZEL8A4ncCXPiIkJ2XhWs3bHjnWJA/4BbP0Ftd5qTfd/UNiFCDRPFsX8qjMochGyPQuJqhd0dcJZ9C/2IhlhWQjxi4wzc2QyRsYfN5CTrbh1FN3f36LzQm5KV7lkkHImekOrsP54cn5KQLvRV7PB29/29FWFC91ay8EAbLnPu761fMJEb4J4Kmm3/Oxp3oEIl/2U/fMr8@KMBc3qP59l7ZO92Qi/f/1Ir1QqNZqbZagA3n@3K7hVVfcKtNQWWBU3meOg@MvEkBLbokmB8XXusNMjqDsB9PrTPoWPsiuz3rxJWoA6rPSHPvh1cgcAwv5n7K9l35TeEjfTXAI5mEiXkaFFUI4LkyIzX2NSgQVe2cLvg7j4Fne1yBO9B71CFhEcedAJcCgGXvpFH6HUt7Rb8RCKgGb/OqPdx7EIBvFpDvAbATFqVhetrp9uV21n553@CGmswrv1ja0xwvFtjDPFejQFwnY3kKGZK5Va9sJ0JxGntNg4GlI4fChBJ37IdUG3pUh1nR1czwcAztP2XOHmtWw00kwypJwtE3kQ8MoChT7oj2fAysHZBWJGFUUY2QJP3@6CaegsTazZQ6WHi5GB7OoQU5NkDZoVXA20QeSgMa5y8dnoDzTWH@TD/g515n8ARzAa1w0n3XqB/@pd/aTvm3psQ/iMnLEL4X9jh72nMoNfOhTaNK9ZgtrRLNWTAcGlXfMJZG3XCIxYeESVlKiBpAhycEYZgcJvYdX3XeHx3beAnNAIwE6terG1JeYL@4MOuYYc0jQ0MPKENk41ywYJ2AGVNPMWepthRGgYIOhFPxFgaiAzNXIQhyUYY0myEfv8hyBo1k7STH3o8Oj4@Rh6D52ThJHFkM5Le576Pen5YEboPsJRti9whyANZ1jkg7dTJ5tvnAqwfZ8Vdzst60cMRmBl2u8BI5SMBAPHjaMXhhweGQtVhFTS6IlgmUecL18YCA0chHj@C7S7vIgoBIhs39ud9Kbvr/Vfsl7IhzeHNZvB0MFgDgx16donO3ffo3rxXHhy3bgQC8@sdgqRA@I93@HqvpCfz2svY99JHGNcGfW4oKt6TLwK1yBehI1GaTfg3eorHQQX04n7xI6CEngA9ixekkaoZmVyhdFGtNV55yRJI70swL/KeHgfuQ@Hg3cMq4H0h9S5Ts0W6cZUtuqzcpGq9tIUh1utbL8ncVdpLSt8ovWNvfr8umyS8KohlvhUxmUGGimQJ@DX2dSq9AZizN@delerzf3m@ezg@vVf2XhX/464HCPbCB1i4IHRvkMcHvGiHzim5W/pN/PCXEXb9wyKe9eMxK@84@34d/baf6@pRsrWzq@s8gB1dI6d0X5jRylSWqfAbbgVQ9zBtF0U8PW3CXHpB17ikspjUdYE89Wp5cpMa5NTl9VNvjsPfiklVe3pKHPk5BWYmusTb0AZR0PYklnidwzSmZK5nPjCbwktKZIK3IJMZUBWrrc6@RBZWON31RFylNISJFGq69GDFsXZeBUWGnTKHUDdZ6h1xJ3cWWrnHvefXGjY0WTJ92KHUCuNJItTG58cVYI9lAfujHqcfHOdX5PqoBoiba20K/KqpGlpPzPOCG6rD3Azlp4AcxEBAF9MJwInkUhfwKCGgihqCzMBHr0vEHZTic@oQnvTjUHp4KFh9aQAjjc8fBJX0C5ZdO8hy/gBMqL2gh21WneE93E3G/Cyn3g2OcXdcWFL6guXDD3AcPmDuQLx33pl5/Z5XMkA8ix034/5LF2NXWXCm02vX7rkvFEI6vVIE230nnQ4PDQq7L8K8AkpsmHoZgjCG@sQJpyHflPhoGyiMyK3v3qcEDVP3o9ApHs/mSEGBAJmRwIUkhBHJKZKQJONVSB9@sslHn0A741hD6ePLUtLQHRsOP0CYFOJH@3hNIQfmBp6N@ykwOCHLIUELAzD8HWKK5jD3whTZ131SLIUXBHSA2plMOvJgSDog8ILUGp1@h9baYN0Dba6m04dOa2yrwzQCsTjeoTEA7Q4151qcwF/HBw24hpUYQOVgqimBQvl8KSgK9FcfyMwEeifipiBkuj/oPnUbXD@xRUrYs0k8d5zagNDtJ7kK3i@yCvbMPn1E5rVHzzDu/3CPB37RGfoX9O/RYfroi29fPlnQYIz5T337wxM2ED0IBPaVA9@@gs2R777D0@HnfbB2HsOesMcCoNC@7D8CeQbr6GRfOdrnjn37/ZPIAckBt4GA/wtk@KVBh7/sc8/0/ndgTQQhRrd7p2/f8OPuwITD7DPQh3vIPh0Emfni8yAPeWYWF78vBQKYhvD@Iybgl/R9I0DGlfsGTWbeR46RSw8mrhrZtlVWLfHqGWCbgU704Uqjx4lzsr138egCbz7ItSNtl330u9/tsQmYRH1KRH3qp0j048Ee2vvsoQ88uufLfX7mvePESPjpoTau1W789z6QSO9eruphYx70PUIHNLVHHzA/Jmn6hx9@AOsT3Z2GT8MP/ruQ9@HOZ50mkwfBROog@NnL2pNomJCxrN8XifhpdN9A90mOOwjEIp@VI0mSNKPfh686xI8VgiV2gqXkA3x8bM3rjUe9je/xYwWfPn2EP/IPn9Ut/v1IYpxoAvL689GPfE8WtXdqffPnEb7VLAm2aZaNgImx3GNZdm9B/h5xmGU/4KfCEx8/fwA@CAHyOTz8TCY3yJNMeVSV3KAhgMeRugfDoSWgHkJWCH@oPb7JNTmE/3v4r27iv/YY/6E6j/@yY/xH7f3y5CTwcz/h8KMbovZ@OP7h5B/xIfUAHsKEZO/09OH5ORC6C39/FDg6wl/8D53ZDR6Rjx0CIh4CocDx3fFx@PTUOg09nN5Re1@oPeuZ2ot4QPLuD6i9E@u4Tii9y586ND85c@wyhI9DD3e1MtjRzWDkOLQXKWZywUijld1j4S6@vsWJUXxbL2Ty1RZA18qFTKNwVmoXWjWINx4eTz9/DoSB@5/Dpw9AifWLwGngxDRNdPt4EEbvfh53hOxbai9/arXo0DEQW3Zi6qSY0D3c3fuhsB@pvbu9O9@nyKcIIzMzhh2z4yu1av9bVqyaqH7GN9UqJEsWM1J1ZsgM2T5IGmKEFrNgFhYzUatsH4IC/DETCEqMaDEDRmEUll2he/9/UlWvqiqgUiGbaTEmxsqIcB1Uq1eATISCR/AnMQxjAZ0WM4N/RkZE7NnvHxlSbT9zf0/dIc8PAiiDMOsNM95wwuuVHuIJ7enLcyTxdEdMhXj64U6wJPPBg4Lex/u7dDrtfTjao437e9rWj55IzHOEQZ6fHx/zmWbm8ZHGKyfW8X7gcyD0GT4np4Fj5/Jpr3969On@MIQFPIyIlIcf92jM8PDxx3vK65t3Oh387cxncztEAnbcfWeV2iEf2g1ADHxmb@TeDli7RMTnu4s/fHn2@/0f7r1HXrt2Ph8SwCj2edh7KyKiiMdPrOU0DDVsFBs0ibj/9DQRh/tEyh/yMSTZznLv0TTt3hMms@8w8XY5OcnoOrcgQDEY7e49nP5477mLPJycpOMkOh5KJ5Cqh9JRv8fv/549PnbKiPgh2uO1PKruRV@eN/98X56PfeTjx39@P450fk/9Pkj2x@HO@uKzjn3HPhwHUTjXl@dTHCRwXyB05/M/@J@f7Tj49fmPbZynfuAcXmL4J/xXDWRoyLv3vIetFAXF4n5fbyH4YwlfKpB2/k4@QgV8nqg3CvXyeDnv3d3ng@hBMnb36eHg4cB3fBA@uD992BoD/N49BPLtyuMJu4f5Ru2Fj@oeNuLxYvk8wnsFqiyEZXWAoumjbWHwPvoOXn5SbDpwEPh8d5BO22UfHPz4EboSoIPCPPDZA/lFPnR8erwSqhVGy38KsF@Qw2QIP38BObMTwejxObsB9/cWQ/qoHx31Tva/7HHPRwQ/evZ4j7bkleD3eY/IdpHni2ef0@/YB8@zZ/9L7xlbhwesnxgh8djR0UHMDidTEGYP/PYKaJyBOzcMKYLB8aQ3H@1hcfICz/1Qq5OeMJAUsAi3mBSIx@N0BH6tXyQKEYs6wtsq9h6OJ@SxOxBKpQm@PWQYaQomID1o@TlKMjCiyjKnI1UUP9rxMJNCPUEAY1aQZbweiCcaYG/L/TlMbj9Se6B8wKgxBPhMapwwFYT5dDoXVp@cZBxyI@QbwUQZf3769R/89Ov/8aff/MlPv/mDn37z57/91Z//AXz/Br5/Yl//5D@k4/j3t7/6X/63n/7qNxD5X@D7n@H7n377q3/z@/aX3P8dfP/vjbi/c74bcPaXAlz//Le/@tO//u2v/sVfwPffOd@/ePn96c/@o/3//zh/OPibn/7s7/CPc/MHf0L9/d/@Gv//6d/@/X/@Nf7/3//Xv//bf/33//zfk8Bf2oH/99/9B/sXCv/zP/7p3/wh1OnPcPifQRj@USBkfwIOwB/hyB/3GbDv0P2Pm5A/0iwMHIjeiPwj9OM99iVk15CA/9/@SDMwtjE25ArnJuQf//ZX/@qvIfbHzwjiHMg/dLM7MrQFuUUnFPRHAPlXGwB/9NOvf/@nv/4ffvr1X/70639OgZkK/x/hb/2xqAhCdsxGtGVRrB36uAWMSLx18GIkwPHxKMj3q3gH06scOAmnxdmtXK4@WtOwmXN7FLKoaGw784tksEN3J@ONnk@ft6A/kvruKssG/ETSP@4sDJdx4PLrdX6SDfKTin18bX9/sj5beLPe2qZ@Gxv@UC9Z@xJsR5zLSWsTtfW18AYKB@dW@Zbd5FuAdnuSsraK3oCxXmDfdb@BdIWRWhOyurVW0rUuirLh7aC1qpTzoagkatXgp146O29uXJuFTO6cSqBstZJ/cYk7QHFULhSbq9uknepmja9QdAvl8stb59JVp4jnsKomZydY5HSj8PExy1KnjUITIppVxEaYMHV6g6wwqtWuDY9HpfAI8RHFk8FgOByGH3wNkg@5hve/d0HYty36PeoK73OkWdvtRMI5IKQLabzRDgPLXCF@Dj18hMZUezsSLjgKB3VpMDSROVdXAIZhgEG5sjRdM3NlbnaocxjIJvihcXxgiYkn2JKIGCqMh71IJJ2Kp9LRSCqYSqdicTYRjwfZSJBNppJpJghT6xSbSMXTbDAVS0djsVg6CPyKp5PUnqD0JZGmYW7FejyIBCSFx09BHuPHSdXw8JTa6wuipAgfkOXr@z/s9d0INE0hTzR1zyAPTXvYBIU3Ig@sE08kCuhRlAGV6aE8S8SjPSaXijIwj@vhm2wqmUlEPZ5HkgKfHOPx9PFNkkkVs0mPR8A38RTDJLMej4hvisUcUyx6PFX7Bn88noV7wzBQ0BDfFRIM9kX3SPgml7HhRvgmksJFeTxjO8W@mbg3SQBT8E00ihEgj@dphQ4j1@2iUiSXad8wTDbn8UztWqTgz@NpEnxR@EtBpoydFCMVzJIkBt96PDn7JkbQnbkY8E0B36Scm6KdggEBnQx3PZnjxx7PAIIDHQwYj8cisVMBRB5C2C9TMTmPh4cbfsEpkE8cmsIys8gMsvDJZR8H1mBgnfE4RWpOB1ufQtFJGb1MwR@SMm5Ord0pk8V04CZZVeej4xSlt3j9WeKUpzdT5I2U6qLarzbxh6QMBm7CoLr6kJSdH5wiqg6YvXKD59KPIhjqnjUCkkKusmV5jkCoKdy90MLn/0JmqD5kSEsBur@PCU5hChb/NE15EknP4QFcPZ88UQhaPsR4waj2eO89Hv9d@uGTJxn3HHo/fQp5v2M/IU8y7Tn0JJMe5D/yRKBvxj2eBIqA0N@CHSoMQl70yXOkC@ZUV1Dk6BlTsDxhjggl6MmHr1wQ//b8Xxyw3tEzXgEHMp98y0AgCF//J0wxzCVhyuw/XID17j96puljrDlYvJ5CU9QpznRiL5oDIEism2Qrl5V2QDBhDocRfEMhCqdrJzYjfJ60D4GlLErwe@8hEwl7JdPn9SYjXq/fewRIPiLPhkr1HxFikc1Un8sZD/ACOJOGea9TfV86BLMyFEoD6a9I0seHhsnpeGmblHiIPIm0B0fjw/PSbmGfgyE2eHjQix@f/neUPUtIsNTeM9XHT0/G0ugofYQXmmD6enzq5LlEi@QgcL5B8hG178VEe6NbpsYe@d3HluVeKKrG1L39/X1q77h56ol6quHHY9pZpTqlyfLU/elR7CSHlyHA8AzfPx5//PmrdThz@PSzu8Z2ilcRX31iMUoXsBNWH5@/Z68upOKYrwNk7AGao8A/5AMlUyeAlDrCE1DPnoY7DC8v8ComurcrevzLPbL8gGpfXKeYqUL27Q6v8C6NjztskGfc7x6Q/5cVSf6SioZOyTI3FlEELf3cSH@f/D71/VWr2qoWPzOHqcPU/b3TnEHWy3pJUzmra59hKJPqBWrP@NGvxtlfKhdHe4eaNxrzgll9f7Jn155N@vdOI8mwwS32HhyXUl8siSUW7smcNMKiPbGz/Zlv3cwmZNkRikr9Xn8wkCK/d/XDj/s07fXC9GD/9O7nM/SRrL/uPSR@GTq2/4/hB@WqNoGeRNzjx466xveP3z/uIZiXIk8kjntTgEb2zHNznuyzDpTvDxT4Ew4M8icI5FY5OD6FKAMinHsBQwj@A5qmryNgQaTTiVRij/odTb@3yQ2pq10fURB0YzrZte2T0aUrDm@JKautHwhcTZeCDlf3UD3X1EDY1sD7mtjY2Ixz7I@NKHIW5XbcwqCxax2OpSgckshZp0jEKsqHV15M4iKFDvBJoNiD2E99oT4ArilvEq88@DmiqA/YPQzf@ly4IPrOMP3YdYbxUx8@OMrWMMOG@YiR40xOZIg9op4pzB6u3zcQ3pEjnjC22zGHna1UzX5QSF4gO5NBRhPbaiIew7jcDYIPkGhTAbU5QKREQjmunF38BxusNxUxKcVSuQB50AkSyc6uk9uj9/CZT6R6H0W/UzhiIApjweCEUwQcAwI6iPQR3P4J9m3mfQQygFicLpIdYoACKzJIKAki0cl4h28fIDtGL/KyagBiu3SfXQN08OgU69TBHcNwJYCFuHZkfCADnT7gg07r4cMz7h786IvrQenDqegYRdYung4uaAz7uFaSkZ/0bcEhh2k5bCbY2IcgNO2R7YnnW8E5MWtGPVMHZnByZDeVdkRd@nj/F7yDePTLyXff8d9rd5OHI//kxMTXQGACw9XYJ9kgB@bJ5ATEQ7uTHo5MUBHSw8nEf@nD9zASwsj@TIk2sw2/UzeouXICtGAvA8MfXN4poV8qD8HinRIAkqfBg9uTZZA7YYIWfKUTNigHn05Ypx5QpnmyDChH3DF88Wbm1kwXhu4Ad7QVhbOMffLJ8o57OAF@yJAxEChCZYBO404OBB78ULgMia8zHsnffccF5FPrSA6F/Bjq@@in4p0JgYfACb4/9HHH1qfl3RTyH/rgegLFyH4gHvI5vH5e0Q70HQGP7TZdk27TaGHyLCBvcnJycPvp4Pbg5OPH5Z0VmjwEbfYfMmtpwMRbmPijDS9S38GtH71gCVkN9Xl@IR3@InxgIE9QAiPq4DaobeS0KTy4hRQNxk@H6mesL8kpku5GOZYwx/PRPnSLHMtDltvJYZcGOeDX7GMfcMibMXhJcsBt531Ngikih4@lDCJFVUIcgcBpzqm2OPHe@vSJcot23PKgZKxcejBLxlNNcqihjpdmyQnJ9iNXX9Ovu9Swq3NX875G6baAYI4ZTWx0V6KaSIczdP4Og2A18IV5PrI1lu2MCcqGaA@AIdoDw4WwFsFMcvSEA3niJEJruQ0EubCeEO3nivCpTgbWT6De1j0fVIhNBnTmHWRIwdEJ0U0gTxKEkHRMyoMAdBXqA1QC04DrID2gU1Bk6LvvkHN7fAIT2yQeCzAYhhsFWAz0ilIo/BsoBRyYyhHIKNaHpBCg7QNOwS7EWwXF/nEFOU8A@CBDYBS0HwQIkwcBfFPFsJ9/wXzz22TgtvjwYRQ4iTkEwT8x1yE/pD3/bs8Z7g/BWLmqtZqF@lWmAb8w4UitD849XB2x@upgRQ0fmNiTFOIwy3N1Vuhe8GDCgPEIIqX28QHKfXTRKqNIpJIP4iflgfV79jIQDKiHK0yCQU4gM8KqPqDn0liit09gx4fdEt9cct57yD35FpNDBmd5/VTO@qEcAy/zwGDuPN67dfb2RDAM57zIkHsENzlmnDyfNMGP2UAvdM6XJG5PrucG8RPCuxJB4n2mSwOJnKs8tBFs5SdHAZp2dtI/KHwuZJ8zOSzRVDrFMIeICeIA6wYibiDqBmJuIO4GEm4g6QZSbiDtBFgXM2tjhslhNJpYB5PrYGodTK@CMWYdXGOIRdbB6DoYWwfj6@C6tNiqtESK4EV7LjdJ1xV0nMbGUm4afk5PMUlkHNCwLyNjQGjkFSRkj72KhPJS25HJNOMUVKKrGCgSSazvQfu4sCc@m6qgTUfQLtm@cyJhrKLsyRIR2IKug1YqWPggXBA6/yHCTxlQFKhdxMsCB8aAYIKVclIE@Rf8h/bTd/ricP2kAcZwwq7uITs@KBLysORMZ1t8diRHdiXb2CI7sdkPRKIVYzYe03CItKk83BppbYyxrbhNrB@xgsUcfQMiYkPgNth@rsMts6lPdxYZfb/ILYQ7i3xFlI03visX5o2PID9xs5Lxn2A7ccuz7RSBtDaYAc4B/kQGXjQofgzz5At76Pntr/7i/0C//dWf/gb99Fe/@f/@0/@Mw/8R//yfYLOgyArgT/4U//xb/POv8c9f4Z8/28hE4KOHnp/@4tdw@z/9e/TTH/ypnfSv/toTjK0QQQqOWuf883@Gf/4Q//xfnmB8Bfjnf2wD4iye4DO1ZVr5AOpP/gtCUBrGskL2F3@DkCcABobPkbw7u48/bDy0ZSNYseGOhB5eptu//FDHbGf8AQ/gde7Y9V0AN4B/A7nO4RPp130PzBnbWRhraZ7jh/jBHCdKNbD9w2MTRjXCA5C3eR@MHmd5wQu1/@/RIfIGMAxEk6dPT2wd7tTfqbdnnYphAx4aqMOHvDqocNi/ogSmtxTIN5kJLIwwnraQGSlry4jD3wp@44U7gHhcyZJMH@unnLLc3DDpQc7B4fC/nupiocXDkP30JjnAn3KeMWE3CtxSNy@aDUp5GQNTxvXzXJtZSYQw0aBJINuK35ix@IZwIfgS3brlnG5TqBZfdBj86YGJOd7USKuCTpDH8xVYzGkH3o8trug2vE2vA3DHHEYftp4O2wXsubm58VAbcQyWIb3vIxg2KmWrjFUSu50U2UiKbCQBzTZOomvikcgLGsjAgfXi9pOQdrYNFbWdbS1cuOe47YDJgLmgva4YFOWpMTx5jZpo5G1l9xr5Bkr24cTpJ/cK0TmnyON/lQFwbuc5edmWu1Ezr2BeN9TunJjbWzFbrfU2pq08G52CcI96yaVVy7HpXS23XeA7qNmHwDcWFGH@kQWFvrGgRPzrBb1sVpx3C/3b/P262nHVxErDr5HZHX9va4DCQ@NfgOit1RGmWCdBnx@mPBlnytObq8i344R4iKfdo3G2joXXNw7MwZOYimoK9vLAZ02FKYeKreCN18rsekWU8xaXgaLqgrH51KdkP0GjePFzx7w6UGBUC@IjeiTnnQd449k@s2J7XFmNbI4VmrPfVINR24zClufjo6RI5uMjGJ@y6F8zEN@GefxYg5fCr7iB0EZ@38q0rWo@FR81Zvq/jpPYu3a2psSPfVXNSfRCIRkEEzpekGHyhYYcP8YvayIswVUkz2Bii7Rn@vyYiUN1og4ERcWPXOPcL9CX1rgxQZymEVqCiAsifoMiZxLt44Oc38l6@bOzosuIj/Ov8ke2EWwxI4j0lzzGnNV3FPf4ZnF2Nre8xs@nt7FJb@N9ekVJN8yXNJNIvNqDrz@v6KhvjQEA12REv05G0Dll4RU5W6SsovGbF@wM30xiXzB4GP4wpRkAzTjgYRHkI7i6M@BuRXj7Lf6/34Bu9sK3Nh8xZhsL0DeTArb9yBTNIKfWKLzgA/CSH@ue18WtRDv/jWU5Ex0ywwsiD1FcCn46BjqmpgmKsdrvdRF/ReaxR8wruSduMid24g6a9FkQjSNvN1H@sS/I3ELo@xzI4AZet8Z1gesTffVtFceKjig91X7dho8JslumGHmKkQAdviEyXHDm978tVjaItJIeshlHKCy9zT@ycPdSNeNF0BN7D0TVQYPukeNLyKEx2kJb2E8@y/Zbvhw9ao8/dktW8APhX2UI8MF@hxMbXBfrf0991n2rKn3DiLCCDW9XGT/c6GLEjxe@bsOfx6Kv15SsMqwynbitvGWdvNXi0nstviEVrkzaVsm3ieTXhO6bZW5D1GxkaxWW@3lDyCvMOU6Wed63idGOebfFVOWVTsBxuMVU5Y1R5XGHQl3lJJrOxEeln9j2hZ@SIFiC6wyubbhihDAHfbQFyq0btmvdJS@SMuG0DavFibnjsS26wUX/5j7iBhTlhvFC7vOqTP7NMvlXZfJbZa56wHaRG0AUv1Wk0wq4ed5rAlkQzTe0M07CM3e4vKe24aOonI73Xr94Je@hFETemfcQFLJX8B4WfKCUvX3vYZ4EDO9hgwTG3sNLCKz7lvdH76HbLTCADrck8BnHOyoc3/Pew5zP/0yRdzu65Ya9h6s2BZhP9i3hyLO9vNpzdv3V1aqqIARtozKIsMQYcFFxte4eguTLwD8Bdc4Eg8SPJyhyQIDxBGRr0NgYMexyYNgIk5fH@XYNH4fu0pSzvrFeQ4H0wMnGogqWkinRR94977YysgnDqWTxEa5AINabh7spQuyrmdnXyHFKBwkljbxdPuFemNgDfR9JvwPgzUUceZ3fba9tFHYDfhudOPNbdL4ixy2OUISdAfw7yMJM/cH7TqVwW784X8pu/c0Wer1GgBsx5ILYrUTQbuh0sOGwbUoK01RtW0hIKt7tkzbz4I/TKbH0vshGtILTM99IJtFOzbBi2Oz8/veqs5EPk7algnDiHfNg97LVuEB0MU5a67oNS9XufEDChs7pk6MhBCy2eSdI4Gx1EyRjxVvDkJvXLpJorm01CZnD@Dm6KWfapa/3ZfDTdT9v@urmBBMcaMQINnKuSrH1q/oz7HfVtt9dg9plwosCdhnWu4fS1@b1u6PsC8rldbGvGxAnBlHev9M4WpWwZjnMDjYs8/dk7ZWJj9@eYxv5dqEr7C@sfZdtqznBV/j2cm5h48JWgj7bjhzjhdlx5G1GvbZI5FnYNVrCuCQHj13xFaXrqr1Pq13xXU2MU/AYDZef3cD6dgNvNh7GRyqgv2C53cvx2wjJPsWqb@M19Y2dC3vXQcVeYqvT0jYiQd0T/7WVixZEVB/r@Wql3IVBN5lM@l9vReBeC3nX4zj17jbBatoSCeKjccg7krHvxFDVzY/3iue1SxmJAGOAI/s2tvg5fdzv6LINff6i70I@G3aDow6u8bobcFtaCZs6HB6yJYev9unNvgPOQeKat8DvIJmt4V0jLB14Q@fxkQxfj4/YOefx0RnFcNOstpF@t@e8vCmy8aLjvW1vpjfeQY8XAKYT@zW7zgKcc7KE7Yeyh19pvXqD/SrXVDEl19kBrw/hLaqVZ4QvyvrtN2G7MfYLq0FSfZEYnsJG4vixZDsXhsYLn8S10inno23o4GNTDU1VnDdaj@23npNDXA136ZWQPVXmHHEDsUshT1NvUGQ7ZLn7YuQlteS8bPuNwJxiLyG7vAkiYRAmOz6RNEw5xpJmn5y2cv0w/CQTIZj4aAGPe7IwwS@KBdndsZp8JUGrDIvSYACCRDtHktsOLk387tiQKoZy7okge6hNXvfrnDjp@ISR016ddWBgp2/rSBcDRRJgTaWDwNn1FxiL3WQQPraFIU5aBAq@Sbgk7WAquJH3o2/h376y7seP8X30PeKWtR/DlHR8/PiMUzb47DydubE07WxaEj2wsXPpnk5EOadJnZB9yjD2UdN8nj2Pe2YTDtpuE5zMu4ed@PAxO4fUB4UoHuwBhnjbtwYMXAUbbWR7zb9ySVXQL1A0Qt6lCOURK5UUCzjsnb0t7JAGWTGxtnefo2A8v@h7foE3E6kPe1gX2rKG87uijMPk7Mm1LKOPDjp7QwV3ZbsLuDfxjZsoTDU@7Cj4o88TACwBj9@zhQngnd2PD7bmfZ0VlKL/d3Szn@gU1Uwm05ywev0sM8gMM/Uu3GeZcqAzihVounAu9zP5Um9xpiabMzHCNLvX2V40UEv2LU06n@TOtQIlxbqTwG3USp/HlvFcNJfhmRvxrCzGkrkb8cYQMrKQpmej8XVfqGs9Vjeky8pVpb6ki63r9uB6JN52OqOk0qC0@m12cG0J16mOMmu30iXjWmjnKua4MjKn7KKa7CRac8XItpvZ4cWiNB9bpYTaleK5ayHZFrXzOb@Ia/x5i7qdNYeJxvlinGYn/UUmZ/S7yUCA7uayg9Q5378VLxq5y/5Aj/fi40aai84mF6K2GF6eK0/lUa4x4wPaqFhKzCilVprNhVhn3JPPldt6u93LZ2vzMWvcav1RrHM1NXspPRGNTjPCcBSLl6amnipnM5dJM58ptYvyTdu8XbRTNco8N5vJ1gWflgOzqslHp/kWbTBt60K6bMwT55Gmeq5cyKVRbXw2PavJ2nScj0nV5iSmD26KPTUSOb9uzM67ZUqPXXS6qfooksrzFk9fxlV1Em2mK2X9yppmn6pCJ8c3skIvwWTjNwV2dFVd8NVZuV7v1LROa5I0Lln5tsiMqOoN38hkx8XyJMU2K4tS6qzUmOZyJWvWi4gDNTPtd6JXN4l5uSKUOtd09JybmlcBKVeV6dHFhbFoty5LNxXjFrr11YUUExdWtp3Vxad8zriql@mKPh42YiOlr7WTUk7lL2qlmFkaZ87nndt0KTsWxFpvrI6bHbkzNaX8iC5Si9z4utUT5kVpOecKsXL7mh4V6ryZzAyiDXokir2xXDWWg7PyctCY9gb9dPWMyQtPl/1sO14vaOxV0YhVlAXVbWZFaVm/FtlxLX1euu0VMtKVEs/VBK12dj6zIpGuJNbm8SVr3YyKMcniY0y5mr25ClxfROqBciCbranR6oCK5ItnnUH8MqAWhSVdFrmnZC6gT6cxKz/FrwYutxRZn8RlJlVsBoZJQ@@kr67mPaN0U891eHmZur0ajxO3depmVjJUPZK6KGbSdG3M6GfcqFK6TUpKMTbPnsmFdKmzbKXMQnkqp87Lg/xFXc83J/xNujBoLBbjQepCqJXHGUpI5ev1UW/Q7lndhlFbMFcxftQLFM4KlacB9ON2oxi5aGUTg2k92r7MK7NasxhYqjedsparjNlCLTVNNJPRCTWzLlKZhqlIWv7sKp24nkrlQiY/aOVYVRBunvhLdsw1mgsmZST16@LNtWYEzGZPjfWG2eji@qpLt28NI34uUbdWJ1HKjHX@sm@ZF0ayqUTU6jXDXouVlhyfdaSnbk0dZSb0ZetmSffmy6JVM3mzMVbj/WR8fGYZT/ryUr@kUt0RJ7cqObU84hOXXWmZpOOs0uzmxCu@exFhMq3B@ZVQPJ8Nli1hEhmdP03PeY43aplu70xOzCwtIEZTszLVrHRuBsmnJ6YnVLppKTNu1WslM9Lk6Gm3UY4/lbuGUeRbJSkbk5RpPts9G09ytwuuaVjLaTPRk8VFTY8wBcqqdK/a/EgdGEXjlh8tb4q3ytU0kripjsSk2R@zE4ktt0UmWdHqgXygJp/1BotEeyrMeLAMteuSxmYzo1GVqrKT5Cy7SBumcmZcVnq5i4yUyZRTkWstkjwf587Orb7UbrUr531Ojd32ctFEtTdgIv1spTCoxSaDZK2SjJVzVLO3uK6z/XxKYoecnBtdLGJauhzJJuj2vH5@PWoOlYqcy3QsMRvlm@o82eFEpSUsE0n6igmMhukLJcPEagmqZebNVrk4jwaUy9JVpLZY8Dc9bhrlxKeuEeC7y@Gy2hY4VR6Wn@pssz0t56TRqJ3I8k2mmm0w06Ux57RyjUrnawqbL1uz4nzY6DCGlj/XUj2r0s/VakJP60c1sVfNWCIz63Rur69bVWVycz05ryd71WWfG8XbplhPVC2TegKTpz0rt4o9Ky8a4qg@e1LOrOlNm461ziblVn8WGKVvu7OodFNlypVsW@SmpetB0mxVLO3qQhZlehKpDmhq3qotl6aQUQuV@VXXEtvLZUbKGk@sdUlz5bNS/sYMpAvFTL7abHC6XK2elfMZbjK/mpdvkgFh2bjqx6Xx0y1VUxQ5ot825GSWiRqRVjy/zPGjM2Z6lp00L5ppVmNb5@2rq0t2KPMTPtmt5hOdK76TyVxcLi5Erl2rabXLVpOqBpSb29smXW3K5bRYLtWbarw00686nSQ3VzPXHFOKTXrzspWdX02nnUn6ItA1BS6qLgWBrc/lMi2cg@ykKGE6q@UqNWMReVqOngazvHrTTme0s0QmtxD7M2G2ZDL5WYA2ita8n5C0VKTZtc7ELn81GFzWs8OoNtOaiVycukiLV0q7lxtepRfC5Xm5XZyaQqPfi0kBg9FGzetMy2jxC@mMTwxnLaMrQ@cTtXgzm0sb8m0@dalLASbFZym@c8XV6PIwflO56KvznHXVXuRhypFixRoTVxdKe5oaK@eXRvay83SZSg1avfMxFDwd3g55qRXI9nvCtShXqNuby/a4UJu26dH1zVWy1joPpJZR/eyJV4dnXHrRXFYZRhDTg1lpakW1Mp86S11WefnCqtRbojBINCLX8pmypPJKcshkRHY@myt0YBHPpgoDMduqKHq@xZ8nBbXG0bTVuTWrnZvUZeSMuWYakzkTMa7mNCN2FWnRrXS7kT6VnRmXWqfBzgqBczPTbYzq/JlMVzr10lJdlAsRo5Wp5MTL6XyhlReSHr3ly2c5ucZLLJgl8cSgqbfGy@ysR3VEq5zLppK3kXOQIMOQ0/NujBN4QxtYI7p8NT2XrdF03NYDE4uuB267Vjw9bA8Nmi@Xm5XSvKDH1QtjpFCJBB857@ha0qg/TRalnJkftltyLJduD3rV8y591RQv09e5xm1SiNfo0pOQ7jQSDF@Od3iarauTmQkjEj8YU@UF09d5WdC55LT6FC9Mp4H@YjY1A9pt8uwy1RmMc@yM5wLRTE994qz2hcxIlaQwMKqd@eym2AELUWnPWgpVvG1p0UvpXGyct6tXY7aWqS9NOpvu8DexQVdnRUWc1aNm/KIkDJK8mC/cjkf589JTiemKT8yclfXr62jxnKWSYiBrqn2Zbl9r18oywgmZbjV1Ne8vc5NhRRTOS5G83q0n@o1LTi7AMCo9lRmtXTwr3/Z78pAWVaXaqDMMdZuIFDo39Sd21r@uLZuqda4PLjI1OXojlhS1dtNm89c6XUlmi9e5Uf02t0glarrcE5qDVFOZBM6iKs9llHKCSgozIdvu0C1BirJJa9njxgLN3nbG49Q5vUwYSzqjGPNRarBM984mbOe2op41F2P6bGLd1rI37FQIsGyN16hrc1mLn511ApeLs1ZpILdKIk9zk8XIOM9OhYt57zqRCaQ0phko9NtDq1wbaJ0Cnez1UmwjGu3EzKd@bWFcV6h2vnweTeYXpiUWxtOKlTrXMonGwmpdx2Lj25FVTTUS9bjFztRxIasVB3FavTGSitU8HxSzQkG8Eo2rZY@fUInltFIqpgqBuMB1a91bRizQT42@bA4HYvPyJtpI0Hz8vFqb397mM/QkKY4KJfkMxsQ5d2UtGqPuuHddNaISpVa7gVJimVg2bq8rfaXWubga9uaDZLKmn7dH6emyq9WlekBbtko99Sxfm8j55Q0IXKKejo9acqHVkW7ydaZKmYlOZg42OJstS4sBXYozl6LCXFiTs/TNpJMYd8ft3KzetcajRCMZV6fCMml2nuJToZXsXkwaNN/rzoeByBmlNpaLm8J1TC9X5lrZrKnCJZOKlG/HrUlh2gpMcpfFnpnrMFov0inPp4FcHKyC1FU7Han0LkfZ0vjs2ji/jqSpZlFaTFOjs8RZoAaDyXRkVFNtOSLP6A4tt@czYTxhuEqea@tWr1Us9yv9SIrWAlJybl4mni66tVvO1GIKTRmLRH/OBc4LYEHkpW68EWibGjOBuQhzM4teKoNoxFBuGg3ezKnJcSuaFmJFva2obUsdtSPS9VlyPOelyxGVFZb9mNyqd/oVaznvp8exPteYtTLFG6UTzSna0DJ0NpG@jLS5p9pEj1ZNrVZu8VnlesJx4jxgydn8ld6YUf1BJdPvFJ@m4qwdq2ZimcVNn4lNb2cjVlneFLqRUa2XGYrzeie2rM@j2f4Zq9QnkjbRIzTTbCuFccpqnQuX1MWyICyGqetsrR1rXY7S46g8GDdqzGJclUT@9taYsqXuoHzN9kvxdvY6PT4XjYyQbKXFixFtVXrV20SuL8QYKjAsTehIrsxHLwo3AfOCl@NP0pKtmMu0qCwqLanXGMwyWrk/ak0r2XM6y0ZmZ1Z1Ej2v09Epl52k8pd6V5cpoRDPWK3qVcIY3mbMdkytRWYp7bYmDW4i/dqQ4ydMIgU6@Krfu120MvXsvNytnDeMjDJYCgF9fqmclYrFrEKdi53Kk/HEqeI0E2tVy93rp@uMPmjGe6ZRYq0ngV4slOpFjucX3UzJGFfaFw2llGQm/exV8nrYLysttSZFLyk@nRzfJGmlwV9MGSFWy8SKT@0z/qk0S9TVsWLyzcIta1bqoOxK8VZV684ny9yQEa1orHBjVAd97RZ662hJRabn9W6/Lo4Ua16/MNuX0UmDHbfn8jihcFogVkhXqxw7iOJJWPxGVSaqfDkwbxqV2aVO08NlYipoZ8KlRJUj2iBTqicuItzZWTefbrGTp7IQSV3Fppl5pFq/CihxQcuXBhOZyY3rI@FagilDJ1EbXTCNitQa3E5zN@lFg1p2e2JauejM1cvceJ4fz0bNlhWF6VWzXTaMRv3G7Jdmkd5FUu5Vh/1mvpi75nMcZySrSq5QHWvTdm8yP4/FqVExejO6Sl5Ig8Q4WRIW3cuplq5dLEu54Xks0FUuUmaXM@Wnqjx6qvRMs/eUlNqN6wu6k03yCvO0SJo3ww5tUOepSeEsJiSXpSGbbCmT2XTar9YVtbSoXV8Bm5ORaPOsR2e0znXNbPfPBf7mvAWW/oUqlBo3F1rj7Oa8P@0rlBwF8c3R@uVZ2Sje5Me37LxUX/QkNjCuXs6r8WRcTPcCs/ikMpzm4/FOcnJRmRXzmp6wrkDrD2qLWlmoV64odnLVLYwDFyLLpvSrZXsWq2eEm0Tvai7OY/F8xlKGqVSLsa4vzvjrVE8rzSetC3ZwTc9v02NjwrW4eoZXxSqVfdKii7xlFph44TJxfnMtjBLzfmEaKWXmjU4pYaYrYqcTe5rX52OhUmTFpjWbR2rF6rWpxOJW@/p2fAmtEKf4gXVdSApXMaHPSMvbnF5Ue0qLyzD0BR2Zt9rXAXWgPFWEwLgWKUa1RIGxahzMjG@z04t@otcayZ2z7Hl6SPVjfCHQNBKl28TTzdOVpN@MAskJqJyUWJ9dX4FJ0jNbzZh1Laa77LKdS3W4XnHJFi7pTOz8fJouRSIX5XS5SxmN@ASk5WkeubnIy5HrWrsZmwbylbzVHzZuW/Xc/Cp122UntU5jdoEnY1GamYvVUb21qBStliQkCuN6QcxSgdL13KimNbGebxd0utYXi7HR@PyseCZML/mpVVACzKDUWsyephMhdXElc4KuFOvmMMNHu6lx1OJLWubpsk0tzrnCBZtLtVP6WOIvRpWWMTJmHU2UMrGnuBUw66OadBnP15s3yqg1rFR0PncVSRpCftyYJG5bI6s3Ewr9C0o00zNets4qCVPJLorSTevq@qLfYBZ8LXVRKeoW06OLTw1mZtKtVKPWHPQqulQewcAZ6LZUNSWDSjGH6jXFacMSM29nLvupgZE7Y1LlC6vakioB5rpQH@UjxkwP0MNJNZJfqoWLqDhPDurXlxNGz836w8BlLUnfjrLqvELFzX60wxnjdF1ku902rRXqS8O4SrV6gctrmRbqkdtk9nzJNntRrT8ddlPdydnsqdu9euq1G@fQnDcBIdG4eqIG15fnRlJM82y/lc2VM@pMYy70SV2MTcpqtxXpioGulS/NnyKXTHFU6rGVynC5zPIXekdJ5Se9qxy3GLVSbSpaqDL926igXbTyT93icDric2WLj96o50bgJlaxpmd6KplgY@kZZ0Tbk0k7kMrIUiAZHS6GkWxhlsjTfb3eoQrVQK6jqtAL6rcJrkIbsX5FNo1WstkopOu5Yu68fFm4EcvpRom7uQl0r0u5QqaZuLgcjmOXXdbI0tmr4agRoUbl3LhPm2ZqKjWkolE40/PW8HZ8PZn25slZ2egulUtuKg0mrMhp405ZSSYy1@2neJWJFq7owu1SViLJuJWm@rzYv6Dl@vimk5IK53RXHsIEOg/yP765muq8qBvDdAdqfrVUkrlWddDWz@VhDSiUe1ONFydpaTwUordUnW6kismOfCny1W59kuz2pJvmRTQpTi2Yv3bzy0sxT0Ort7qN4ZS5SRTAdI3Fnkqd4eR6Vmkb9Xi@3SzXYlT7qZ4X2VKhXG7fmn22UmUGxZnZSqbOCyw/yY4rhUW2ly3Ni3yrcx4YBSLNPj8rtjNyod3nDGtxy6QZPSOOqMQocZUV86w5j7dFPZa7GFajnFxSrepFSpvUaxeR7EXhWlTHOpO9zrifRHuRnkjxxUDMZM7apW5uQGWuc/lRpC0afF0JzEsELFuUud/97KNCBF1XCBg1U6U@Ii86d465OHrn4Aly8gR@vH3r3Ans7LN5kIDoPF8NtEA5QU8LPyF8aBdC9jbD@OUGeGvx6OXeYoh1jxMgF3yOBzogLzQQtzZCPTrOvCLjo6S8RwDZ8SQ7KHgfjDye/AvjEL5AQ9BFCWwiT9T5CG/8X6WNcASf84GP7mQejja2PH3sJjWYQGgyThGBn0HPL/CpCt9BRrIFXKgW/bu29ZmjrfxAnKEp5KQRTyjsIVmdUzEwpm0Udmvi@NXZDBQ5kMXdWHvndU0czaaYRJqc74GUoBmc3KUfggf8iQcJpsQpE2Oqz/vjgTqciUhG2qhn8YvlE0LxGIpCWZHv7NMy2cQJTQ7KTcJvCqUZ53go@zRLcl4RPiSLnDaIz8b0IhRaHTH1EflJIIh/Dj1Hr6QUHUxcKbQP@ZjcJR5OlBPmaHKnPBwpgYDfDJyYATbgwxHfsf4jbep4It6ZD@SpffoAXbmP1uOXGWDfX1VENVXhh6rXQOQtw5vPnJDDwNwONOG0zf40E3hT1TdjRCxP3GSrI76OwrvE3IuckurCmQtNwFt3q1MJZPx@dvzzYZqIHb1OxzX88AEfoXHk@E5sVuALpU17ssQfUh8IP/EWOH6c/vDQORSGR1huP3wgcZIdadOCJMOHk4/cVF7VFk5myQZ5dOtyvIHy1If3Vv3Bb4F0oXogk4/41VM6gNkgNnu3wBGgJlujfpsqHC4LymofFJ/j4z/Cp5ygj26ae@IPhsdyQ87deTSRRE7pgcsxckDJGRjI75w4QWLvJPzQG3ElOPXaSR9G04lG9p/DNr0OR/DbMh81TtJXOcPGFL8O2YdYzAzJJRq3AA484/PYZpwpbDaN2xbY8Y08fIXrg/HVyMtRgGCe0/UF1o344QOMr6@SPB/s17H6kKnajpU2GU5eUg2/09TAOHyMtVfzHiLiB3cEUWRL9GgjdQSpuK5vJE8gecKZwzeShxj31HgrWYdk/JLWN5IlSLafidydrkK6vdP/BoCJvTxBXB9N9dHkJNlnH@iBjwJ5thW2DwUCLmNXIoDshrHbYzs/co5GQR/t1rGFbUu8oH8SsbIBsEj7nM6D79fSQlLxKd8@Wy42yrR5gr6grxbmOEcCix9JSaB2cfn@gy38aIMA6H@gStHrdLdwu7VXFd2SnzAMOwPc2sCsKPrxx/cocwRxW/7YB1f67BbCfrgbNbS5tcZjv0Ny3a52pqWTaXce5@iYTe3m@kis6@F2yshahdh9a92vRUnpQxmA@ONmNHZ58qNP65g74wEdrrTHmo92t/g6HyOvpAd7RJEeGUS9dZD/dq5yWO4hJwcjcm@tLPA5YdzRK3YaK@jQNvQpQK@4@ULO@C2ZcXrpz63st9VmD@gjnZrw5shWtDyYhqcOgTvI4@x23dQJNrJ976Edj9@NKW0jk95AZp@n9wgIzGOgAY9srhp3x0RJCdvPpIKeZyKxIHExt0Ge12xyldW38OmfoHNhxjlD9hS/LmxbJaEdrHkFvqo35tfpyy73onq2pt9duTv7oWbvJy@mEb2WJyJ1n2CUPEQMWh3cdISev66H/mGc@bJuvi17x/C9rSvcRncl8VtE8PkNRn9VyLarEHlAWxzHJBDN8JUhiRxCuHtQWrvWP7oxrtul3bfftMAwVUfb6ZhmG6GbAIbyZq6gY3OdrlWnc/rio@kaN8G1FYbf0mlLBZjsR9SmOsfTuSIZvDdjV0dHEY5spuAn2bGFqbuUSaJr24IZ7OYL84@4mW0mY35Cnx6oat/nGkyOwUAwuCd0AFDQPs5qZVbZ5uW6eCjOMXrRwDnlwx13jyDmoxNFxhWIwManI5uYiIMB6TZHuNts2DeSQV4iS9LxaARFuU8fYGdFW/ugw5fxGHplAn3YmcnV@PhMMnJypaPnyUi8pR48OU7BjqG4Oeyp9bEHx68aAsOcwkR7fb4laYPn/7@4q/1OY8f5nzt/hUOettDCBNJ29z55uyWEJOxJIMtL25w02xKYJLMFhsNAgL3t376rn2R7ZnhJsrsf9txzm2FsS7Isy7LGllZ4GSSGp45u@Ud86@Lv@i5sYjvo5hRkZtdSs7eXAhor8L/@ubmxNQlHWzf@YMsbPJBRfTN3NpU3kNxpO2oyvs39hoPCxfrJJ61N@Fw2H0IkMaGRAjZ34E3TqEOWM6KIpjKOxKTjQ4sFB3GA@dx4z3voktUvEVuGQTjjf@e0Wci7k@E44BKNiGPXqZ/@zyieap5vEekdgyZnj@FEddK4XyBv53JWMlcQA6mAIMeZGIgrtGSFm/qaSmH8QKg@T3p17YSu1@7cgwjI3k/ZTtFwsST/ckIz9Ii1Blbg8go99iTKxJDPjgIFWyfhnH9T9/G7gAd5w0dcIfd6n@LwgWCU9IJgCCHHUVC03yMGCONfNJpH5Xrd1Vlt5MQ6TrnLOWZcEeSAdZyIwB7jxWl1hAuUQXmBzgK24NuPgLP@ZR4BrWYTpsIU7BReIR6h9CBX4F9L3bD1M1KdWcLXnfSvELzM66geQ7KjwLuoWTrWLGeamcoxVrx4khvtTgeBIM69fkAUl7xej4gWXryI2IFHcMTgf2vxh1fAeW2Jl/LcUnkuUe5KuRAV1XI796Oo0k68Umrzj6jeL5WKqmWXcO0r6nSlytGl3GAUo3v3sbqhS5s0P6p8YIdSpNIW7CUKcrGSv60YfSnZSLSxAm7Lr6Rcy/e2HnlLZaLuxyR@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@uEGOZcVXn3XfvVSVmIpmC7Xwhn/9QeO84pWA4l6uN6U4GsN7nADCrzrDQfyLZ9B6Qrtgp0orBFUMy/UNv9OB1Xcepe132Ad9MmCMQ5UnoSRRljvOKN2RbId49mbv9MKto23UP9YK/WJ8ldm2HA2tkHdwhGnqjvj@Wm0bBg98FA829qdug1wum7IjGlSXhBxr1vTEx5U1GJUniuLSaFrZdOFwscQPJFTiA303wwHGkNRvITvURfp8vADkIoggIcWSSkj1GCeHr9Np@H@K0ggBEWYo4YAigrnUnHe9RGhwm4t@kQemOdYPOBJF522Zktkj7BTxXaLp7I5@0b8RgHhVuFqOdBrh5WmmoRu24@blYLyt6vqjXPlWOykfq8FI1T8uqVLu45GRV6rR2RtqloYrVI3pbbdYrh61mjV6kig1qmeICp1i9VOUvF/Vyo6FqdVU5vzirEDQCXy9Wm5VyI6sq1dJZixbrk6wiCKpaa6qzynmlSdWatSxjNc2cqJ2qHavzcr10Sj@Lh5WzSvOSMR5XmlUgOyZsRXVRrDcrpdZZsa4uWvWLWqOs0DHnqNIonRUr5@Ujl/ATTlX@VK42VeO0eHa20NHa52q5DuITvTwsE5XFw7MyY@J@HlXq5VITHYqeSsQ8IvAsqxoX5VIFD@UvZepOsX6Z1UAb5b@2qBIVqqPiefGEOuekn@AKjUupVS@fg2jiRKN12GhWmq1mWZ3UakfM60a5/qlSKjd2lXNWazDDWo1yViEVJ6MmGMQtKqfnw1ajwnyrVJu0ZrQumpVaNUOD/JkYQ1QWqekRM7hWld4Sk2r1S0AFH3gAsurzaZne18FT5lYRXGgQ10rNeDVCSExsxrupquWTs8pJuVoqo7gGMJ8rjXKGBqzSQAWCCbyfi4S0xb3GOBFd8kjC6hjJzfJwqsqxKh59qoByXZskoFHR0sJsK51qntNc3nJWfnJ79APe8lc@7Qp5PEh8qXZUJotPkrOkovctWnR@S368S5TRQmML6af@Cspr1beudzO5@@YPbgNszW0z@YLdD@@ySFGUQSLUr84jCZr1h3JusLn57dun4jfa5za@fctkn9MyQcZTLXQU1sdqZXQfe0G7y9v8hG8pzqiDVzrWe1YCL8d9La@s8yGjtra6nm6Gy4sAbNxEOikBAetCM/KtxvZAxVDyJ@akr4gzZiw6i8znzSCkfwY/ox@yNsRekHKWcwtbW9jDMhnIfKIs/YSEk4LozCB8DsC/ZZRu6Hk/7tL5ODps@bWDKmPacN0xbQPv0pknmt94dwvNc4vtmVjcNWVjxYSDN2HaIZgB/9IsU3pc3BH3LC2uPf6TMdQwIjIKM4KKL7Lq0yfpV9Ic8UXFV5jZtaHEOR3IefFL5TM2c/nt97sL70/te5lbuHWO3Da03l1xu2v@c3otFWiC@dh@EUv8uXxS3dqKtSGrjO1JWxmx6u9Raep3aU3FUn3v8bKOCPkSLjjenhbjkT@LU09q@KRePD9sHR@T5gS173/78Oc/7To64v5o/CUrfy@BB/kdmbtkRU99MtO4KDZLSmT3HC8ly4ll98HooSJyK5pB45dtMmlt5EyxESS/hriB0N0QGQYGSLKRQpKAUUrhfr634Rh5XTkztQCkE13NoDf99owt/DaZSiwDHYmS2ZvzqM3wD2Db6W@muO2QFiAtYl5/OJ6T5NLmgvVe6tgEHOC9DV8rRhU3ZeR42DZnkIQx0JkchQF38PmXlu3YKJJdi4HGfOVh55ZExMYiFSZJC6dcIhQXQWhmsLz06c0XLW/0eKmTA6EIqR6K4wax8di2zJnkPeJz1hNDQ74@2KchevXKYtpTcKRmNFHi/0@mjonPBiZFDjSoBcDm5JHlsy1hJ/TH1xn1h0gqonoDzq6WWP2bJHdVdzSUXRMSXf82GWSUwIoSyvCrqcXhmCqXpoplZ4JN/xU/GP7/kCcr4O/RhpOgR9xiPewPJt4zOclQhVe0e2Wm@FNzYix2TC3iZvzVZQTmV3xg7m3H9DG8mXxYIhbo0ZmbF5eSUiy9ggEQcvg14vMXAXx5Et@3aef0kefuC/nSPxp0@sO0SchllooluNdZtrmy5ogcfmTkE35exdCdIb/KR47zyDoDGy7SYjdz9TJMCYy3BdY56PTWG3Z62FnOogk2FMwMj8Qpr6eWmfwzfcIoWmW6pvQXmaLrk33ZzyHIKZRQ@OYLiFEgfPYp3mHNNsJ5AEJX9huRXtjLr/QqjoyRpAJ5XVZNDs8Rtm95z4ylSMfSQNAOoAScl12ds@nGG0@xXPQEOscQiaCp9EsOYwIk2hdpzQijfDMucZ0X2amlnt2UkFdLfWvwY4C0wp64uEwNN5EBKh6C1VXnbU4G1Xtev1MR8rdg60ESf2XAcVU68r0SrjneuRMW7PRfhhFHyOKcwrqkdSjiUrvzAy9TRkb9ac6f0R/GldM9NzmNaM/AGetWGf2/1m4IICsLZ2BV6uvAOpF2ZCHbf2nMFzzJ3LVPl3jSfuZ96hQRR29wYFabQSAZdhMOaS7PNqYvEVYHh093yHKaTt2b9qTfHty2@35vzqdO/x7cD7bCwSQcusO5k0qlkt5ABAJHiBSifeypz/6gG0xDdUjTAY6kRrXVuEg6/mKer5J4vpT6C@FQh4zZWQJ/i5hJYXA7pqHxdtVc59keRe4e9hNqTwu7teZ4gcBUIxYgwtu3lvFJtaVOvIE3Invwgs9cqjO/4w1IfZAxxacww3vRNKh@DOwNjV0dw3Zhz86u8nx26ljfnqMRaGhZiFaapiIRPNJpFeGbn5Oox3yC7nKHo351jVPpPhjqaEBwmsLYFBfn7aSXdZC78XOleYrNuGzM2TdDy5rx9cGXKKZTX5y11JlRezCeE1OcRecNkf2U78ZVHAyIIDrr2cmbuj7Sknfh9uuF1FUkSddagFcQmqqe/4BkceyGe84Y8Tlb7TaL@Lar4ytmJX2dUR2J0XOi0csiZ6ibVR/@XzU9yK666LU7tMNSjQmav3tHduBhEI5R9byoVH67UCjkCu/gom01ii5PBPxvMog5TuX8olZvEiN1iHwjGHbNBPM5aZecxiJ2FFzk7qLuf4dGNg1IZW5/Z@7BBjeBfFO78skitZOiwe@04e@lLoZJe5h9svDJByPOHIZwUCRDifnobLsKYQ@QpI/VJFDFwGc5eZlOPyaLi/POUMoB/bjFd1DXI9Hq4ZPod27N70gHeDN@57x3aYixO@jq0Pe5A9X3@rYD/tis8G2p4HxwFxKfWa6JQ5Uk5HX2NUwlYmEmDqjr4aBEiBQC/fChMyIF034guTMxsUhoWDlleNxMGCesKgxrRcoBmiLdoG9z6whUx7ER3fT7YTjvBGrzjvbK2C6FQ8/rcrqDyVDi@aPcpanaI/Uvsd52okD/zmaeDz@OSGMgrwopsEkPAWARsO9Gxs0xokGSYWIENu@xNxdA1KHGmGca0q6lV2yTswofazM8cG0aU7TNgA9rovURiGEWX5aIKhowHlJ@4gHPIqZUjwdsMZgfGnJGoXCYLAAs@TTrJQsMePRdPy5VEDHbtwQsxAk0xEiwK3lOOLKSP9BfHB5F5LO09JE6N89YZh77yIMpG/xA3QX4F5VdwzH50Ofxh76l6IMzxNUleIs1C8s1qZbNAhKrub0CZm4lzHerYeY0TP3FsTJ44KhraMViIb2QkM4BKTkwIur@SWD0J8eG6wXylcj2/q4X3CD5Es11woY/82w0sPHXvI1KMDpemnEcs@zxoRcuU/u2ad7pt2diPOc5vhl7AfxBNGldfa5VSEfFq46yIdNQ/dqJIgAnvgoLDvOTT3jxgeLU/6U4o1I@GU5/Zk6GsYByrUT5nKNMD9K6QxnNfv5howtnDDG6X3vcZBCbQ7bDUuAkuj3CVaB0HEtmR20O2/JRCrVCqMw46ivmAT4Cp@i/NyqtEeTixEolRG3Vk5QYz5F9r2inJMNiZmjeibQ@/4pNPRpBRzQLn0gSBZVOJ0bc6BQLUx6XtAqBwnsBx5gcCS8Zktkgb6HrYkLbgD2BLJnahvBmZP3zJ0wGwZrROkT1SwmZa@VaE38VYb42@izZi7W1F5XcqjoxfWe58Fhlw2zLp7WV1@tBZh22qJiJUj3GujP4IDXrzOLwOhSWsR/eH3MszaDjsxWxwLaYOpC22RWqITnkhrjsQq@cWKRs3cNFBeckdHpCSNKxX8gCrl5KnjQBlHESrcD/dQOO03Txib22XkHq6WFfJxEWlhn3x8TCVjbj/phYSOXYsD8uFiZVnmUtt1@Ui8RICAtw5k3bo@yyiOsgUzCL15ot1GKC5tfxUNleL72C2phW1a40Z2kRtyzSmTGSOPjPTAZmU8exTIgjMe/KjsZ11Fsytjo/vK4N@Kt7bw3wg1RySZDRXIxzj04bDDxG1xlkZLYNSGOLj0VvyfpyNJADpr8WW5i3OEgKdXefvDyaAGtWlXxm2dQxweEj4vdWEp9bDtIfme87y@nH7eElTTXO0wSjLmqnnBUfFJ0nqHoboyrZu9gIJVm8BlLuWZByz4C0FYOkJ/Y7Wi/5cXOENGjeUyC@fl2GwX/@Ria@hkGatuvDR4pN1rQ9fwrmRookh49steXQkm0QWXBPwfh9EQannby3H3v0y/s2nDr/8EbBYtKHtZxNysoKiixVm8tkZUEWa20253Q9Yyrxrsv9cXPvW0Nv8@mRljC5ujFOqt7bbwybyaDtFlg0/wtr@JeNDWtyPgjhiV2@1005/@Z0cMEIcWDITaRon7MY/Bb5Ltf2PvMkpo@y24@5HAqEWjRKQiKM8R8pD7OaGP2zyrB/Ev/mSvzDYEg2yO1KArh@H25c8UgsqNzIdFzYlD1rrVm53iz3K25XLaSmeP4kfLXU9W3qOu4l06QbeFO9Oj8GWffFjMB/YGlfGRlZQ@TLlUTiO2tbu0XUYNK/8UbOc6aitHDxR/Yw6yXXcTY3VbHTodmrj9AjQT1nb/M0SpipEIRQTYZw14dytg@TD94VTwR4sW43mA64tpsCCnbR9b32QEdK1wva3Qjua1s3i@yNuNvDGPxBhxgdejHX13dJSdz1dAkOpD7C1t3VYw@pBk5NRTbCpMkSWzA9T@455e0aA8RaHVxrZ9GQMLKDb2FvxHLW9gwZzpnVzpPnWDePGSwkxOtQ6g3pAujHZXRnPTMnQ8tKOzTPYOUqc8h6OJ9hDs2faw79Dzi5OKBO7Fmv7noB3HlSqS1uwp1/AQ)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))

### Explanation

Braille is a language that uses the Unicode braille symbols as its commands. Because it uses a hacky parseing method to find the braille symbols any character that starts with an E2 byte will be interpreted as a command, but If it is not a braille character and gets to execute it will cause a crash. Because of this I put the Braille code first out of the Unicode languages and the Braille data at the end of the Unicode languages.

The memory consists of a tape with the code and a single storage cell to the left of the data pointers starting position. The `BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK` marks the end of the string we output(it is written backwards starting at the end of the code).

⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘⠀⢃⠛⠋

The commands in order are:

- move data pointer left
- replace the value in the storage cell with value under data pointer
- If the value in the storage cell is 0, move instruction pointer 4 places back (into storage cell)
- print cell under data pointer
- move IP back 5 places (to start of code)
- exit (this is executed when it is copied into the storage cell and we jump the IP there)
- the other 3 commands are used as data to encode the characters for 138

`BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK` corresponds to the value 0 and the value of the other symbols can be seen in the table on esolangs.

Comment: It seems that the Braille characters have been breaking emotinomicon.

Comment: @WheatWizard In what way? seems to work fine to me.

Answer (score 4):

## 142. [BitChanger](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BitChanger), 6181 bytes

````
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\Dv'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14" ^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(x>77*,68*,@'1    #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;iiipsddpsdoh coding=utf8␉␉␉␉(1P''53'S^'?????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxOBxxxxxV/112\n#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#cTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzLz
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@.>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOO0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11xx4O6O@MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0     )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>+.--._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWW/wwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQs""o
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1 "
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _      @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{^{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .002158 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 6310 bytes)

This program prints 
**1** in Python 3, 
**2** in V/Vim,
**3** in Minkolang,
**4** in ><>,
**5** in Python 2, 
**6** in SMBF, 
**7** in Japt 1.4, 
**8** in Retina, 
**9** in Perl 5, 
**10** in Befunge-93, 
**11** in Befunge-98, 
**12** in Fission,
**13** in Ruby 2.4.1, 
**14** in Turtlèd, 
**15** in Haystack,
**16** in Pyth,
**17** in Julia,
**18** in Cardinal, 
**19** in Reng, 
**20** in Prelude,
**21** in Nim,
**22** in Underload,
**23** in Hexagony,
**24** in Thutu,
**25** in Pip,
**26** in 05AB1E,
**27** in Perl 6,
**28** in Brain-Flak,
**29** in Trigger,
**30** in Whitespace,
**31** in Modular SNUSP,
**32** in Whirl,
**33** in Incident,
**34** in Rail,
**35** in INTERCAL,
**36** in Labyrinth,
**37** in C++03(gcc),
**38** in C99(gcc),
**39** in CoffeeScript,
**40** in Minimal-2D,
**41** in brainfuck,
**42** in evil,
**43** in reticular,
**44** in alphuck,
**45** in PicoLisp,
**46** in Cubix,
**47** in Lily,
**48** in Deadfish~,
**49** in Octave, 
**50** in Bash,
**51** in Assembly,
**52** in COW,
**53** in Shove,
**54** in Zsh,
**55** in Brain-Flak Classic,
**56** in dc,
**57** in Wise,
**58** in Ksh,
**59** in Tcl,
**60** in Moorhens,
**61** in S.I.L.O.S,
**62** in Grass,
**63** in Brian & Chuck,
**64** in Agony,
**65** in ALGOL 68,
**66** in Surface, 
**67** in C11(gcc),
**68** in Python 1,
**69** in rk-lang,
**70** in Commercial,
**71** in what,
**72** in Fortran,
**73** in Morse,
**74** in Archway,
**75** in C++11(gcc),
**76** in Trefunge,
**77** in C++14(gcc),
**78** in dash,
**79** in C++17(gcc),
**80** in Klein 201,
**81** in Klein 100,
**82** in Brain-Flueue,
**83** in Objeck,
**84** in Klein 001,
**85** in zkl,
**86** in Miniflak,
**87** in Alice,
**88** in PingPong,
**89** in gnuplot,
**90** in RunR,
**91** in Cood,
**92** in C89(gcc),
**93** in Set,
**94** in Emotinomicon,
**95** in Emoji,
**96** in EmojiCoder,
**97** in Cubically,
**98** in Archway2,
**99** in *99*,
**100** in brainbool,
**101** in K&R C(gcc),
**102** in Symbolic Brainfuck,
**103** in Unicat,
**104** in Paintfuck,
**105** in Emoji-gramming,
**106** in Unlambda,
**107** in Gol><>,
**108** in Ruby 1.8.7,
**109** in DOBELA,
**110** in Ruby 1.9.3,
**111** in Del|m|t,
**112** in Pyramid Scheme,
**113** in ADJUST,
**114** in Axo,
**115** in xEec,
**116** in Piet(XPM),
**117** in Stones,
**118** in MarioLANG,
**119** in ImageFuck,
**120** in TRANSCRIPT,
**121** in Braincopter,
**122** in Monkeys,
**123** in Mycelium,
**124** in C(clang),
**125** in Gammaplex,
**126** in Nhohnhehr,
**127** in Deltaplex,
**128** in Haskell,
**129** in Brainloller,
**130** in Boolfuck,
**131** in Extended Brainloller,
**132** in YABALL,
**133** in PATH,
**134** in Aheui,
**135** in LNUSP,
**136** in Wierd,
**137** in Bloated SNUSP,
**138** in Braille,
**139** in Core SNUSP,
**140** in Gaot++,
**141** in Floater,
**142** in BitChanger

### Verification

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZsWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQokiap5z6@yGAG6STdmOlJp4N00p17b6YHE2D6Q9CDAbrRAQaY/tq/4nwNBnP/wZ1VRVIPW/beJ4lskcWqVatWrVq1alXVYqnHGcPf/e4Af1BNlZcDWTWRKRgm6uvSTNCDKLNEnznJiIbCFIWh0vpgOhEU0zimDhCLkKTwUh@ekamOBUVaCTrEhxDSdHWgcxNkDjkTCQbPaYKB1KmpTU2kivuzhRHKT9SRFMA5J5IyADBT0DVdMEl6BKGWInOTXp97kRJ9UaCmQ7qBcoL84@RHE/HqZMIpfQMgYwjlqpl8Of0CQxyhK1U3BIyHFwxDxZEJhBZ5gX8BmgRQTpfUcrpy/iKJZdA5kM5psrBAXM8wdY43JVXBSSxqVFqN2k4OwtKarvanPK6uORQgGbNIlGTBoHioyhnS7IYJ4gA6QLrA9S0wSlR1hLOgyVhGEuI1DfVkbhjkkSwBbIFJIAFzFK0gXR4aaKFNAIOhToRtOgykCEIfGZrAS6LEk9KRsDAFxQDijSCS@DGaS7KM@oIMGTYk8X5AhqbGVpRFQJDqqxSCD6@9qMD66VAAGEVwmCBowFTMBBW3AXDE4cVc5zQNiAQmNoBwU5qAKEmm20ACZ0hYWCGLISh9wj9tLcYq4pTtWqKZxCEO6J3qBLch6LhtggQvGgq6ACi5tSB55rpkAgswe9OoJnA6auqC4N0V6Z0ioTAVl2DiigRJ852euvPVghua0coR5DSTOtDDzesLikPBFDp8PIFvyuU6ofKVHPpyeI/DlgRDU2u6h/Oi1C@RQd/fC/BdsD16oD9TgJUCrsiIVjWT5gIaEBgwgUCaw0EcCsxCQU3eKhidvmiLLeGyoPrQGqikoLaf1Iyf6jrupRumcmOotKwqA@AnVFafKpgfCoox0AS8Cp3Mj4QZcE1VrDZS54TDzaEEjWbgJtnqF5auIQwFbQOyZ3PUKddQ5SmBg5yGiQUQuAJZMcaSiNpI5CQZZ4F0jMqiWheMqWziPFOlj1sedInQDyKHDF7tY6CJOoPiOEBKIqAvTbZ6ICEKgKEhVFJVnPTTv/zL/mAAeNI8r@p9W1zbqK/yRCtyhFhQNQgLrKpwMiEL4Py4dCs7FDDjZKnPmbh4ZWkXQYggpc7VqdxHKhSozyXoWkNuBt1RFAXeFCwhtxSpH024saU3JEtyoeITrgcNSwogZZNqB9DnLLQSL1AHRGYCk6kpJlBAyyO3QX/v@XTs@fTxXgDivEHv0SFND05A4IJHJAqe3O9JTju9o@gMkzNUqU9pS3OoKiEU4JGLT6maoHjcOzjcfrfec3uDWJ95vCdSig@KktL3uEHGM1Cu23vCp/g76fjh5EXu7RIByxxjwb1V8PBeFwUah/SJGT3hJCWoLVE7YIe20lTjEXMcJwe3ojFfXsbNrIgDMo5gsVSxfIAaChqyIGgeJsh6sZbAcHurjRP2VfQFDrvCx9KDz33g9m1XnWCAmu5UFPfVpqRirSVrwynoaGCKYmigvXUsujwHwmNgJW7CYO5HPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dQH1QI86YkR6pNXjcP4A1pM2hk0PcuB2O7TQ3@rPoAugS5vGK6Usq3MomNCGhy/QIAounBtAE0Fmq0Jpq0JWiSRmt2pjBfQKxtYTUCLQk6Av4F4Hqt0W/a06Ang4ZMEANquvbKmgCbcELLw1JG76DZJE6FIT0BL6EvECVj2ggwRrXMGFTEk3NMCMwQYNEwhFo7td7VVPM3U6HbgFXb2i3@1QuPLbfQrrGyQKcyRzymDKDbAlpUAWjucFzbT1FdTEMEEjvRx2SGTAHkODxpA6/PyybDKW2KPrVhlY11utZ4@IHFYyti0VkEGnIs62BlFf0kE7ycuXpQPA7EXhrh8wyA4BP7jeIMExBEDIhIXAT01QbiDI86HED0F2MXWKpR6tsehl8RC1XToo@IC4LhoTw559F6KC9DoKk/EmigBu0dd4YIzFqM52Ikjjb0e8j5kzJnsQq2sSYTzYig3SXBBk7ys4J6qi7kEKjFyjxSC7KVY7gEHWwMYgjF@O9UU669pCXDcRtBloD@j5IH9D09SMYxguJHM47QVBUuimviyZVQULC23qS8lUrXBPVnugng3on7RTAs1Pe9LiRYVI3LoNRwY1AztMNFAKBvCnKUidxy0aoDhJfBYDbyW5iAInKKyrCwAJUBAY5RENopILoFQaS4X3uIKkKwWh07n8yIU7rssLAZxrzZesOsFaCHWIfYANvowOmksEbWXrfqL6ub0j3noMIOad2x0cqZLi@eL@@PGj@9h9Bhr@48dPEDrFoU845IPQJxIKkBCGC@IQyeEnIZx6R3LguAf3852DeeF9wM22wKPTStI83N3xcfjBz92x9j2E715QdaDZADqAb4DH7U2lcNDrdZ3NoaLBnmjVvm5xtk@koS4oA0pYaKpuoko1l3@spZvFlIueGjotSz1agfH1cQI9GOYyrj35YVLiZIdgXVXNFGkwHE@gCwBkz@EoU51Cn4f5hzSRzBKZ/cgKFuxNozmpWSh3g6AmCSZlj0YbWccToU3bQD0IfGl7TiTq6mSt4QxK4Icqch2GXdiW35mm4mHfTo3g1Kk9Sd2Kj@P4CZ5gBnlqwPMooFqP60gbMIEB8aQzCJM5auDzYUgyCV1H2pBJghJPRIN6z4n8wjLPOH49C90aR7Yx7kt/O9MaOUuQG8rU0HDlCM/2TKdt@BgG7qs9QV7EIgFBFoPmYhXE6iIWoawbCvTfgtiTl1qs9mWgTOj7gYX4IoHTKYvCJoxhZZiyoLJkkNWH7Wam1h3knnJZHTi8Ozq5NimhjSm53/51bWMhwgwCMlaxutyEHsHYi@6ggOn765yiZAzJZQf0FUWvU0huY9ITyWUPwLFtU0GXwBN8zJILPD3EZp2qIkWYEzAyOhBkwCpJ4eg6ueFxYh89uyPeDjE9QZzClJHuSQoOfwUskEwQSLHXk94CBb5g0p37HjB92tvHNhCu4SujCO0w3pzqpiz07ft/@/0@NMDr5hlyS5jq8ON14BH4hpsqIL7ZWnZW/EAu@1uWwIymssQRNpDQ11DyHJ6OcvI6sB81VskoEBhyOjTu0mlcEE58geH1HTmzKNcFedoXnPv@QgiLd00vK7ciTUiN4I7tSDKOvpH9heFo5cfTeV1WuT7BYi2zSMKmta12ERbcACpHb2kk0JDfQKdj36HNugoYMubUuuKllK@1q6Th736uHO8KGRPleqwA01CuJ73BR0xG7C3JtjoMNj0CosyNreAjDu6vrFUdXRoMwOSy72@BgX0NUyCN4wV6Tm7viIUzGCAy0HPv4dRl6/oWiLMovA68BQhVlcnl5wgfEQceegiWHbygGdhik/SCsTLXW2ITbfjzpQgXSEZZUDIp3udjwnjAXc@AN0unmvZ2fmwhkPzJ5P7c1iorQcCroigIX@u5MPpIE04OhPpbwTcVsWPSbkJ7QEfcjANjV@YMEBLTZrMwg2Yhl/cEFw8oPBaXTegdsd2Q4yx0vDVX3uTRJF6VJUMjze08vKURX84yNmjwOjq5bLLip9f87YNhjwfrwDq0v1OrvInnq2/I0TcoKWuqiCfjW4IRVN/iHa/O8fdNM2GozgTrun/gWu2l6htUUEAmkgGTxdfZ@/zXxBUvfJLLfi6O91Jl8vLe@GN0par6UFAMFAoy2MxRyGo9DNuybM1dm6Xq2zJtSLJqoAa5vscLmBAYhnXdL83bbJM4JcAPrT62Du/PtpcoMsihNLm@0bicPFDlWGJAc3B5UwKmuog1vX3/Vg231lAs@1UNtTZ6VIW172@q9jH8f004yDqsjpcntoLv2FL71Jk9rX27gjAvwGuO@ytXYBIkZ5C2ZnFvNYDOD@fc0rn/A0aPt7jrjB7akpjMYNPhDMkEBEzdMqP/IaVF3i@t/2066hXa@NcqsdW4Y1kAjU2ur5oUhRj2Z@ZgGebbNZYoT4WpsFeDVHsjAcTmPd3x7UQxdjUO7XUPGpiHt2jXUCt7QvhNVOPxHD@9q3A4WYJO/lVrZq@q0cDO1vAEugaBGg68zjhQptpO427xrj5V6u9zbqg5PVvt7xCJU36uRkp83WbaMcUNgXzfMtvzExWmveoEbAjlG9rfRkqWiKzrDmISs8E8kvBqlf4u3mO0XscE@xXsEWhVaWwE8JLXtyme0FvzdQKcTMKMTBHMJb6@xe19irSnqvLPaR3Qp30Jm2lgfGJfha@10ivbx17SRpuVCQOvcvTEt9YkrLHGnjwC9/BE@c2GrkGVTDI4fEsrv1oDfGfU2loR/NocEkZssvBj6LwTfoveOu7cbDARjL9LsLMqRjuB95Alg@FvsY80x@glC654kdZalt04Wxy80D/aEjgl9QMGPxQmAnl8x@Ln@qOp4dzeBFqo@LsnOUiTJdM38mkSdHgFX3eWgLdMIlNVBIM2OX0g4LmKLHBgjVqxbylZZyV2L3NLE24gFL4qWZtlB7zZyevSTnD/AsSxtf/AQ7avqBFrGqgqY2FpOPf9xvKSh/acTt7Ftq@T83h186u9OkjvXX3@is2nDNWhMhSGOukZ66e3@gZIpGm5Yb1XCaB/yBljvLtrKyTNLKPAE9qa7Q2NbT7Lqix/C5@xarQUparuX4LNY/@qPmT9WXiXXA8S7NtXV@tgBCfsIkP5W71oKExhoDJUU9WEAHl6C1TGaz3Wdf@qcqnqNlBHEvQ@rgmWygkULfVkAc0lIGFkbO8T7F9H6skqh10J3rHlgTPO/VtWpnhV32/TnXOqCWbq@2NvgdDztRE6I5l423/wPqC9CUacptb76obf9vaCOEm3fXuMtQPdQUnhdYHssju7rugA7/1PJ1OZM1U9iAicx8P5fF4vZWXCM@@BAmAOFHFhwn4NlneUgWTJMAmsJKK7O3T4ZXHMHLPPKIVcxy708GBhJTvs@YVGfI/qVta7Q@4hdegOBNyH7nvlGDFuAirIMBHaC8rtwIkSuVl0bqqOFG5CXClw2KnpieWvYQyJSxQwuA9N3oKRnKzaqLrldWC5tjTxcv1//Zu@7SkGqttAE8kAw3egYO9GdSIM1fknq1y79LSmcdjTDOOYD/F6NC49kE0jAwQWhiriIKbOUavQTNj@Jrb/JTzUsMLeosJqVGxEYC8o02o0i5q@KlhiYRe8zuVUilfl6USBbtI3h0YQNaDzCMSfZb0DCSEMppg61hV9PyqhvoAXSvuYMDJQyqo6JlurmJL/@jeWlw0kSliEcNgpnjjZbZWI8OBPXFt4Xp0C1Q6SlaCrNogHMxmU9RTboCDUghXvRfyQI@4/IIkBx/kFF2M5wGTTDRTIIzd2EsVb6ieS6DlM18/bd8xD6pdoQgv/7fdp7xebb65fBOKs4fIjB@TkGcvVdjIDyZtUN3IdLlx2tbA7IvG@WwuV7XLswWHSXI4zy4R4MhK5E@bEmYXsESt4LMIugooB/QMevQS11WlSh56pZfAEGiaKYk9asCE4CFm@j8QpDDtm4CyHC/QjGmJZCfCIjTLwZDFExr5Ak1TG2ewKb@9H0jmhNyVr87NQMBROkeocPqZOz0hIF/oqds27@/5@EWIC94t4/oE2HObc3y9@wYRugHsqaODD72jcgfKV3JfD4Bnz448Gt0Qu17P7xNqfhV5@@KVWquUbzXSz1QBuPluVPSio@oTbaAosC5rM8dB9ZOLzCGzRJcH4uvZYa5D1E4B7POiQQ6fYWdrrXSesQW1WuwKuQyu4BgGjZDv3V7Lvy28IW@mvAWzNJErI1qKoRgTJlhm3sa1B/Y5s4XbB3X0KOtvhCN4t36MKCY9cKAVcCgCXvpFH6HUtrRb8RCKgGb/OqPdx7EMBvNpAvAbATFqXhetrpVuV21v553@CGmswrv1ja0xwvFtjDPFejQFwk43kKKRL5VY9v5sJxGnj4A7mno5fWxBJ37JcZS3pUm23TEczEUvJsN2v1rrVQDPJIJYUljcRjwwwLSHdkWzRGVi7IKzIgigtG6DJ@31QTb2liTUbqPQgccuwfDMCCnIdALOC64HWj1wUhjVSr93zQHPNYfbO/2BlPiRwBLNB7XEnvhfon/7lX1ouxPcmhP/IDosQ/hdW@HsaM@i1G6RF45o1mC3tUg0ZxITDFZ9wi6064RELj4iSMhWQNAEOzghDMLhF7Ka@GzyeuzbwExoBmIlVL9a2pDxBf/BgJ7ZjmsYGBp5@B8nWvrDgiXFHfNqeptilGwYIOhaNRVgaiAzMHIQByUIY0CyEXu8xyBo1k7TUDz0enZ6eIpfBc7KQip1YjKQPue/Drh/WhB4CLGXZIncI8kCWTQ5IO7OzeQ45H@vFWXGXc7Nu9HACZobVLjBSeUgAQLw4WrH54YKhULVZBY2uCAuTqPOlY2OBgaMQ3yTBcux3EAUAkYUbex6/lN3NjjH2pNmS5uB2M7g6GKyBwY5d@0Tn7nt0b94rD7YDOgKB@fUeQVIg/Md7vNLX0pN@7Q/teenNjGuDPjcUFXsRFIBa5AnRoTDNxrxbPcVlowJ6cb/4EVBCT4CexQvSSNWMdDZfuqjWGq/8eQmk@yWYG7nPTn33gaD/7mEdcL@QeoepmQLduMoUHFZuU7VZiMMQm9W4l2TuK@0lpW@U3rG26l@XTRJeFcQy34qYzHcDBbJg/Rr7JpXeAsxaW4mvSvV4vzzfPZye3SsHr4r/cd@rDgfBIyxcELo3yIsObrRH55QcB4Qmfj3NCDoebSHX5kWetR@f9byJftsjd/2y28Yt13F1wC65oTO6L8xoZSrLVPANJwioe5C2iiI@qRZhDr2gaxxSWUzqpkCeerWYuk0Nsuvy@r082zVxzaSqNT0lrxxwCsxMdIm3oA2ioK1JLPGPh2lMydzMfGA2hRfAyARvSSYzoCrWG7N9iSwDcbrjM7lOaQgTKdB06MGKY@NmC4oMu48OoW6y1DvhUncLtHboe88DN2hosmR6sOvrIogniVAbjxdXgD2VBew5e5p8sN10keNN6yMOubUp8KumamgzMc8JTqgOczOUmwJyEAMBXUwnACeSW13Ao4SAKmoAMgMf3Q4Rd1CKx65DcNKPQunBobDoSwMYaTxeP6ikX7DsxpWX8/pgQu0GPWyx6hzvOG8z5me5H29xjLvjgpLSFxYe/KrJ8QPmDsS7552Z2@t6JQPEB9p2iO6/dIZ2lAVn2r1240j8QiEkk2tFsNt3ksng0KCwwyXMK6DEhqmXIQhjqEeccBryTIk3uYGCiDx67j2K3zB1Lwqc4fFsjhTk85EZCdxIQhCRnCIJSTJe2PHgd7A8dAraGccaSh/fVpKG7thg8AHCpBAvOsRrClkwN/Bs3EuBwQlZjglaGIDh7xhTNIe5F6bIuh@SYim8IKAD1N5k0pEHQ9IBgRek1ujsO7TRBpseaHE1mTy2W2NXHSYRiMXpHo0BaPeoOcfiBP7aXnPANazEACoLU00JFMrnS0FRoL96QGYm0DsRNwUh071@571g/@bdMlLCgUVi0XbDA0J33znLu7/IKtgzh/QJmdeePMO4/8M9HvhFe@hf0r9HB@mTL55DObWkwRjznnkOhynWFz7y@Q6VI8@hgs2R777D0@HnQ7B2HoOuoGsBQIFD2XsC8gzWUepQOTnkTj2H/VToiOSAR5/P@wUy/NKgg18OuWf68DuwJvwQo1u903NoeHF3YIJB9hnowz3kkPaDzHzxuJCLvNWLiz@UfD5MQ/DwERPwS/q@4SPjyn2DJjPvE9vIpQcTR43s2irrlnj1lrLFQDv6eK3Ro8Sd2tppeXSAt18525O2zz763e8O2BhMoj7Fwh71Uyj88egAHXx20Ucu3fXlPjdz33FiKPj0UBvXajfeew9IpPsgW3WxERf6HqEjmjqgj5gf4zT9ww8/gPWJ7s6CZ8EH713A/XDnWZzF40f@WOLI/9nNWpNomJCxrNcTCnlpdN9A93GOO/JFQp@VE0mSNKPfh686xC9AgiWWwlLyAT4etuZ2R8Puxvf4BYhPnz7CH/mHz/oRXz@SGDuagLz@fPQiz9OCOjhbfPPnEb7VDAm2aZYNgYmxOmBZ9mBJ/h5xmGU/4PfWYx8/fwA@CD7yOT7@TCY3yBVPuFSVPKAhgEeRegDD4UJAPYQWAfyhDvgmh/9Qs4f/6ib@a4/xX53Hf5kx/iuv8B918MtUyvdzP8HgoxOiDn44/SH1j/iQugAfYVJycHb28PzsC9wFvz/xnZzgL/6HDu0ET8jHCgERD76A7/Tu9DR4drY4Czyc3VEHX6iDxTN1EHKB9N0fUQepxWmdUHqXO7NpfrLn2WUInwYe7mplsKWb/tBp4CBUSGf9oUYrc8DCU3TziBPD@LGeT@eqLYCulfPpRv681M63ahBvPDyeff7sC0ILfA6ePQAli1/4znwp0zTR7eNREL37edwTsh6pg9zZokUHToHYsh1TJ8UE7uHp3guF/Ugd3B3ceT6FPoUYmZkx7JgdX6nVzX@1CvHSghmpOjNkhmwfxAwxQotZMssFM1GrbB@CAvwxEwhKjLhgBozCKCy7WESqsernHXRv/0@q6lVVBYwq5DYXjImRMyLcB9XqFeAUofwR/EkMwyyAzgUzg39GJpLPfv/IkFp7mft76g65fhBAHwRZd5BxB2Nut/QQjWlPX55Dsac7Yi1Ekw93wkIyH1zI7368v0smk@6HkwPauL@nLRXpCkVcJxjk@fnxMZduph8fabx4sjg99H32BT7DJ3XmO7Vvnw76Zyef7o8DWL4tGQ8@HtCnn@7PMMshfEr/7L6yRgX3j/eU2zPvdDr425nP5laIBKy4@846FV86NERZIfwwh8/sjfy7gcVrIfN47qIPX569Xu@He/eJ22KQx4MEMK09LvZ@ERJRyOUlNncSBiw2jM2iWNR7dhaLwnMs4Q14GJJsZbl3aZp27wqSOXyQePikUmld55YEKAJj5r2L0x/vXXehh1QqGSXR0UAyhlQ9kAx7XV7v9@zpqV1GyAvRLvfCpepu9OV5@8/z5fnUQz5e/Of14kj7eub1QLI3Ck@LL57FqefUg@MgCuf68nyGgwTuC4TuPN4H7/OzFQdXj/fUwnnmBb7hhYp/wn/VQIaG3AfPB9jWUVAk6vX0loI3EvMkfEn7L/URKuBxhd1hqJfLzbnv7j4fhY/ikbtPD0cPR57To@DR/dnDzkjidR8g6CKOSKfYA8w36iB4UnexIZcbi/gJ3nFQZSEoqwMUTp7sCoP70XP08pNgk74j3@e7o2TSKvvo6MeP0BsBHRTmgs8ByC/yoNOz07VQrTEuvGcA@wXZTIbw8xeQMysRTCePvadwf79gSDf3opNe6vDLAfd8QvCjZ5f7ZEdeCX6P@4RsOrm@uA45/Y59cD27Dr/0nrGNecR6iSkTjZycHEWscDwBYfbIa62jRhl4csKQIhgcTxTCyQEWJzfw3Au1SvWEgaSAXbnDJF80GqVDcF38IpYPLagTvDlj7QS5Ai6rA6FEkuA7QIaRpGAa04OWn6M4A@OyjN9eUEXxoxUP8zHUEwQwiQVZxquKeLoCVrvcn8MU@SN1APoLTCNDgM@kxglTQZhPp3Nh/clKxjE3Qp4RTLfx56df/8FPv/4ff/rNn/z0mz/46Td//ttf/fkfwPdv4Psn1v1P/kMyiq@//dX/8r/99Fe/gcj/At//DN//9Ntf/Zvft77k@e/g@39vxf2d/d2Cs74U4Prnv/3Vn/71b3/1L/4Cvv/O/v7Fy@9Pf/Yfrf//x/7Dwd/89Gd/hy/2wx/8CfX3f/tr/P@nf/v3//nX@P9//1///m//9d//839PAn9pBf7ff/cfrCsU/ud//NO/@UOo05/h8D@DMPwjX8D6@GyAP8KRPx4yYCWi@x@3IX@kWRh6EL0V@Ufox3vsP8luIAH/v/2RZmCQZCzINc5tyD/@7a/@1V9D7I@fEcTZkH/oZLdlaAdyh04o6I8A8q@2AP7op1///k9//T/89Ou//OnX/5wCYxf@P6KPVAjhO75QrIX2IwktjqhoGOTUCbObcDhCwlG47rM48BbMp887URbuo33ABPATSf@414DBZRw5tO0r7KOTfy@GT@gzJMOYRYatBb7iB4jBYaLyyM2JWtiA5NmCsZ@3clox1jPayr4bjyO3Mjq3fdFWAinSAUI2soVdKNqgt6tBOZRZwItXERSyq0dRcdSqwaVeOi82t@7NfDpbpGIoU63kXtyiNlAUlfOF5voxbqU6WaNrFN18ufzy0b511SniOaycyOkIC3J@UfD0lGWps0a@CRHNKmJDTJA6u0GLIKrVrg2XS6WwTvyIonG/PxgMwgXf/eRD7sHD7x0Q9m0r@IC6wvsDSdZy15BwDgjpQhJvUIMqnSvEP6CHD8mYam9Hwg1H4aAuDYYmMufqGsAwDDCg1raVY1et7asO6nEc/v7cD5QgbH/M9yNMqwwS9ypFfg1OFWFEmeC31bEPlInny5KIGCqIx59QKJmIJpLhUMKfSCYiUTYWjfrZkJ@NJ@JJxg8z5QQbS0STrD8RSYYjkUjSD80YTcapA0HpSyJNwzSJdbkQCUgKj1/DPMXvs6rB4Rl10BdESRE@oIWn7/1w0Hci0DSBXOHEPYNcNO1iYxTeVzxapMDixjuuYRZ0l4tycYhHB4VClikUXK4MfgD1y2QZl6uPH6IJholnXC6BpGQTYSYEmYb4KR9jsFO7S8IP2XShgDGM8EMogXG4XGMrxXqQnYc4gCn4IRzGCJDL9bRGxwBy1aIoQXKZ1gPDZLIu19QiLwF/AJe2niKE2Dx@wAk4U8FKyUKay3XuZIJRxeWqW3B2UUWnvum0y1WyHtJpjOKCVD5qVeoSP6TJBzLp8ATi63INIDDQwV5wuXoQxELscvEQ4pccxE0ghJ1AFZNzuZZWPXBNXK4Fgeb4scv16MRDOUBPscgNzb4wsD5L3brzkFSCJGkxzRd65@e9waCnL9P58zpJurgocqPlVO8NenbG3iN8VJwLksaT5cuPgJMeHzl5f9IlJCkvkh6XjwKh8JF7AsrszwAXNHm8wEkXkLRvVcVGCJ8JAPfwJzOBe4brWUnOhySR@6LXc52A1FK4/6Clx/uFTCc9yJBWAqgdD@OfwmQn@mmacMXiruMjuLs@ucIQXHgQ4wbz1eW@d7m8d8mHT6541HXs/vQp4P6O/YRc8aTr2BWPu5D3xBWCzhd1uWIoFHe5bsHiEwYBN/rkOtEFc6orKHTyjClYpZgTQgl68uA758fXnveLDdY7ecYr1kDmk2flS7F@tPJ@whTDrA3mt95jUoeTZ5o@xaqBxWsfNHWG86SsNW6AS7jWKZbyWPd@BDPbYBDBNxCgcLqWsvjgcSU9CExSUYLrvYtY7NbCo8ftjofcbq/7BJB8RK4tTe49IbQii6cehzEuYAUwJgkTTLv2nmQApj8okATKX5Gkj48Nk9PxSjQp8Ri5YkkXjsan8iWdwj77A6z/@KgXPT377yjLHI@x1MEz1cevZkaS6CR5gteEYJ54embnuUTL@MBX3CL5hDp0Y6Ld4Z1Z8wG5HmIT7iAQViPqweHhIXVw2jxzhV3V4ON6LeCMJitJ92cnkVQWT/PBwgveP55@/PkLazhz8Oyzsxx2hhf9Xn0iEUoXsM9UHx/sZ03jE1HM1wEyDgDNie8f8oGSqRQgpU7wTM91oEHn4mW0xIuO6N6q6OkvD8g8H9W@OD4sU4Vssx1f4U0VD3fcIC/R3z0g7y8rkvwlEQ6ckVVpLKEIWvq5kfw@/n3i@6tWtVUtfGaOE8eJ@3u7Of2sm3WTprIXwj7DUCXV89SB8aNXjbK/VC5ODo41dzjiBrv3PnVg1Z6New/OQvGgwS0PHmwPUE8kjiUWnsnkL8SiA7Gz@5nvPMwmZIUQikr8Xn8wkEK/d/XDj4c07XaDHX549mX78/2X/Z/nu9PT51P8ebYD@PL8/Hz66p/cNp83YDbpvn/QylPw8eAh9svAqfV/Cpds1WKPKxZ1ebFXr/H94/ePBwimn8gViuK@7KORNcHcng57FkfK90cK/AlHBvkTBPKoHJ2eQZQBEfazgCEE7xFN09chsE@SyVgidkD9jqbf2xGH1PUWkSgIujGd7NsjSuvSFYf3z5T1PhEErqYrQYe7c1agY8ggbMngTVBsymzH2dbNVhQ5YnM3bmnQ2A8Px1IUDknk6FYkYgXpwQssJvGnQkf4gFPsbuylvlAfANeUN4kLH1xOKOoD9iXDjx4Hzo@@M0wv9rNhvNSHD7amN8ygYT5i5DiTHRlgT6hnCrOH6/cNhLfviNuM5aPMYc8sVbPegZKXyMpkkKHMssmIezEud4vgIyRaVEBtjhApkVCOK2cV/8EC601FTEqhVM5DHpRCItkGtnO79B4@yopU76PotQtHDERhLBiccIqAY0BAB5Eegts7wY7QvIdA@hCL00WynQxQYKP6CSV@JNoZ7/DjA2TH6EVeVg1AbJXusWqAjh7tYu06OAMorgSwENeOjE5klNUHvN9uPXw2yN2DF31x3C09OBWdotDGH9TGBY1hnUJLMvKTviU45Iwwm80EG/vgh6Y9sdz2PGs4O2bDqGfqyPRPTqym0k6oSw/v/YK3G09@OfnuO/577W7ycOKdpEx89/kmMFiOPZIFcmSmJikQD@1Oejgx73w@6SE18V568DOMw2BWPFOixWzDa9cNaq6kgBbskmB4/as7JfBL5cFfuFN8QPLUf3SbWvm5FONfwFcCY0P2P6VYux5Qppla@ZQT7hS@eOdzxyUSDAcfd7IThbOMPXJqdcc9pIAfMmT0@QpQGaDTuJN9vgcvFC5D4uuMJ/J333E@@WxxIgcCXgz1ffhT4c6EwIMvhZ@PPdzp4tPqbgr5jz1wT0ExsheIh3w2r5/XtAN9J8Bjq003pFs0LjB5CyBvkkod3X46uj1Kffy4ulsEJg9@i/3HzEYaMPELTPzJlsup5@jWi16whCx6ely/kI5/ETwykMsv@XzAZL@2ldOi8OgWUjQYvW2qn7G@JIdjOrvqWMJsN0nrLDFy6hBZVSdneBrk3GKzjx3GIW/a4CXJBrc8/TUJ5sUcPm3TjxRVCXAEAqfZh/XixPvFp0@UU7TtwwclY@XSExCH59fkrEYdr8CSg5@tt8m@pl/3qWFH565nlY3SbR7BDDYc2@quRDWRDmfo/B0GwWrgC/N8Ymksy3MTlA3RHgBDtAeGC2Atgplk6wkbMmUnQms5DQS5sJ4Qrddt8KFVBtZPoN42PR9UiEUGdOY9ZEj@UYroJpAnCUJIOiXlQQC6CvUBKoFpwHWQHtAZKDL03XfIfjxNwaw8jscCDIbhRj4WA72iFAr/BkoBB6ZyBDKK9SEpBGj7gFOwv/FOQZF/XEH26wIeyOAb@a23BoLkrQHPVDGsl2Uw37wWGbgtPnwY@VIRmyD4J5MFyA9pz787sIf7Y5StXtVazXz9Kt2AK8x2EpvzgI/XJ8e@Oi9Sw@dA9iSFeNfyXJ0Vuhc8mDBgupr4WCF8LnQfXbTKKBSq5Pz4EABg/YG19gUD6vEak2CQA9aMoKoP6Lk0lujdA@XxGb7EkZccXx9wDvTF5JDBWd68wrN5g8fAa1swmNtvLu8cKT4RDMM@BjPgnCxOTk8nLzNN8Ds50AvtYzOJj5Tj5kGcivDmg5@4qunSQCLHRQ8tBDv5yQmHppWd9A8KH3fZ50wOSzSVTDDMMWL8OMA6gZATCDuBiBOIOoGYE4g7gYQTSNoB1sHMWphhahoOxzbB@CaY2AST62CE2QQ3GCKhTTC8CUY2wegmuCktsi4tliB40YHDTdJ1BR2nsZGEk4ZfwVNMEhkFNOzLyAgQGnoFCdkjryKhvMRuZDzJ2AWV6CoGCoVim2fQPg5symNR5bfo8FslW092JIxVlDVVIwKb13XQSvkFPt8XhM57jPArCRQFahfxssCBMSCYYKWkCiD/gvfYelVPXx5vXkvAGFLs@hmy4/MvIQ9Ljqq2xGdPcmhfsoUttBeb9a4jWjNm650Om0iLyuOdkdbCGNmJ28b6EStYzNE3IEIWBG6D3ZdAnDKb@nRvkeH3i9xBuLfIV0RZeKP7cmHeeAjylJOVjP8EW8opz7JTBNLaYAbYv0tAZOBFg@J3NlNf2GPXb3/1F/8H@u2v/vQ36Ke/@s3/95/@Zxz@j/jyf4LNgkJrgD/5U3z5t/jyr/Hlr/Dlz7YyEfjwseunv/g1PP5P/x799Ad/aiX9q792@SNrRJCCozY5//yf4csf4sv/5fJH14B//scWIM7i8j9TO6aVB6D@5L8gBKVhLGtkf/E3CLl8YGB4bMm7s/r4w9YbXhaCNRvuSOjhZbp15Yc6Zjvj9bkAr/3Ebp58uAG8W8h1Dh@0v@l7YM5YnsVYS/McP8Rv8dhRqoHtHx6bMKoRHIC8zftg9NiLG26o/X@PjpHbh2EgmryqmrJ0uF1/u96uTSqG9blooA6fXWujwmHvmhKY3lIg32QmsDSCeNpCZqSsJSM2fyv4hzycAcTlSJZkelgvZZfl5IZJD7LPQ4f/zVQXCy0ehqxXPcnvElD2CynsVoE76uZFs0EpL2Ngyrh5@Ws7K4kQJho0CWRb8xszFj8QLvhfotu0nN1t8tXCiw6DPz0wMcfbGmldUAq5XF@BxZy24b3Y4grvwlv02gB3zHH4YedVsn3ArpubGxe1FcdgGdL7HoJhq1KWylgnsbtJoa2k0FYS0GzhJLomGgq9oIEMHFgv7r42aWXbUlG72TbChXuO0w6YDJgLWquaflGeGsPUa9REI@8qu9fIt1CyDym7n9wrROecIZf3VQbAuZsn9bIt96NmXsG8bqj9OTG3d2J2WuttTDt5tjoF4R71kkvrlmOT@1put8B3ULMPvm8sKMT8IwsKfGNBsejXC3rZrDjvDvq3@ft1teOoibWG3yCzOv7BzgCFh8a/ANHbqCNMsU6CHi9MedL2lKc3V5Fnz8H3EE87p/7snHavb50FhCcxFdUUrOWBz5oKUw4VW8Fbv5az7xev7B@nGSiqLhjbr4hK1us2ihu/pMyrAwVGNT8@fUiyf8oB77Zbx1Hsjivrkc22QrPWD/Bg1BajsOX5@Cgpkvn4CManLHo3DMSPQR6/A@Gm8C/3QGgrv2dt2lY1j4pPUTO9X8dJ7F0rW1Pix56qZie6oZA0ggkdL8gw@UJDjh/j36AiLMFVJC9sYou0Z3q8mIlDdaIOBEXF72fj3C/Qlza4MUGcphFa/IjzI36LInsS7eH9nNfOevmzs6LLkIfzrvOHdhHsMMOP9Jc8xpzV9xT3@GZxVjanvMbPp7exTW/jfXpFSTfMlzSTSLzag@8/r@iwZ4MBADdkhL9Oht8@kuEVOTukrKPxD0pYGb6ZxL5g8DD8YUrTAJq2wYMiyId//WTA05rw9lv8f78Bnez5b20@Ysw2lqBvJnls@5EpmkEOpFF4wQPgJS/WPa@LW4t27hvLsic6ZIbnRy6iuBT8Kg10TE0TFGO92@wg/orMYzegV3JPfINSVuIemvSZH41DbzdR7rEvyNxS6HtsSP8WXqfGdYHrE331bRXHio4oPdX6FREP42d3TDHyyiMBOn5DZDj/zOt9W6wsEGktPWQzjlBYept/ZOHupWrGi6Apaw9E1UGDHpCzTsgJM9pSW1qvScvWj5fZetQaf6yWrOC3x7/KEOCD9dNUrH9TrPc99Vn3rKv0DSPCGja4W2X8JqSDEb@L@LoNfx6Lvl5TssqwzpRyWnnHOnmrxaX3WnxLKhyZtKySbxPJrwndN8vclqhZyDYqLPvzhpBXmLOcLPO8ZxujFfNui6nKK52A43CLqcobo8rjHoW6zkk0nYlPgU9Z9oWXkiBYgvsM7m24Y4QwB320BMqpG7ZrnSUvkjLhtC2rxY6547EtusVF7/Y@4hYU5YTxQu7zukz@zTL5V2XyO2Wue8BukVtAFL9TpN0KuHneawJZEM03tDNOwjN3uL2ntuGjqJyO916/uCX3seRH7pn7GBSyW3Af5z2glN1993GOBAz3cYMExu7jSwhs@pb7R/ex0y0wgA6PJPAZx9sqHD/z7uOsx/tMkZ@sdMoNuo/XbQown6xHwpFna3m1Z@/6q@tVVUHwW0alH2GJMeCm4mrdPfjJl4F/AmofIAaJH1ModESA8QRkZ9DYGjGscmDYCJLfxPPsGz6OnaUpe31js4YC6b7U1qIKlpIp0UfuA/euMrIIw6lk8RHuQCDWm8f7KULsq5nZ18ixSwcJJY28Wz7hXpDYA30PSb8D4O1FHHmT32mvXRRWA34bnTjzW3S@IscpjlCEnQG8e8jCTP3B/U6lcFu/OIzKav3tFnq9RoAbMeCAWK1E0G7pdLDhsG1KCtNUbVdISCre7ZO28@CP3Smx9L7IRrSC3TPfSCbRds2wYtju/N73qrOVD5O2o4Jw4h3zYPWy9bhAdDFO2ui6LUvV6nxAwpbO6ZNzJAQstjk7SOAsdeMnY8Vbw5CT1yqSaK5dNQmZg/h1uSlnWqVv9mXwS3Q/b/rq5AQTHGjECLZyrkux9Kv6M@x31bLfHYPaYcKLAvYZ1vuH0tfm9buj7AvK5U2xrxsQJ/pRzrvXOFqXsGE5zA62LPP3ZO2ViY9/HMgy8q1C19hfWPsO29Zzgq/w7eXcwsKFrQR9ths5xguz49DbjHptkcizoGO0BHFJNh6r4mtKN1V7n1ar4vuaGKfgMRpuP7uB9d0G3m48jI9UQH/BcquX4x9ZJPsU676N19S3di6sXQcVe4mtj1bbigR1T/zX1i5aEFF9rOeqlXIXBt14PO59vRWBey3k3Yzj1LvbBOtpS8iPz9EhP/2MfSeGqm5@vFdcr13KSAQYAxzZt7HEz@7jXluXbenzF30X8lmwWxy1cY033YDb0UrY1OHwkC3ZfLUOpvYccTYSx7wFfvvJbA3vGmHpwBs6j49k@Hp8xM45j4/2KIabZr2N9LsD@7epQlu/33yw681ELC7j1WEVeAFgOrF@PdhegLOPobD8UA7wL3WbTu51rqliSo6zA14fwltUa88IT5j1Wj/w7cRYv8MNkuoJRfAUNhTFbx9buTA0XvgkrpV2OR8tQwefsWpoqmL/UPfY@jF3cuKr4Sy9ErKnypwjbiBWKeSl6S2KLIcsZ1@M/PYuOQrc@qFjTrGWkB3e@JEwCJIdn1ASphxjSbOOWVu7fhhekokQTHy0gMc9WZjg378F2d2zmnwlQasMC9JgAIJE26etWw4uTfyTuAFVDGSd40MOUJv8irF9PKXtE0aOhrXXgYGdnp3zXwwUioE1lfQDZzdfYCx2k0H4jBeGOGkRKPjG4Ra3ggn/Vt6PnqV39846Hy/G99HziFvWettS0vHJ6jNO2eKz/RLm1tK0vWlJ9MDWzqVzlBFlHz2VIvuUQeyjpnlcBy7ngCcctNwmOJl3Tkbx4DN5jqkPClE82AMM8ZZvDRi4CjbayPaad@2SqqBfoHCI/FQklEesVFIs4LB29nawQxpkxcRa3n22gnH9ou/6Bd5MpD4cYF1oyRrO74gyDpODKjeyjD7a6KwNFdyVrS7gPES3HsIw1fiwp@CPHpcPsPhcXtcOJoC3dz8@WJr3dVZQit7f0c1@rFNQ0@l0c8Lq9fP0ID1M17vwnGHKvs4okqfpfFHup3Ol3vJcjTdnYohpdq8zvbCvFu8vNKk4yRa1PCVFuhPfbXiRLEZW0Ww4m@aZG/G8LEbi2RvxxhDSspCkZ6PxdV@oaz1WN6TLylWlvqILrev24Hok3nY6o7jSoLT6bWZwvRCuEx1l1m4lS8a10M5WzHFlZE7ZZTXeibXmipFpNzPDi2VpPl6UYmpXimavhXhb1IpzfhnV@GKLup01h7FGcTlOspP@Mp01@t24z0d3s5lBosj3b8WLRvayP9Cjvei4keTCs8mFqC2Hl0XlqTzKNma8TxsVSrEZpdRKs7kQ6Yx7clG5rbfbvVymNh@zxq3WH0U6V1Ozl9Bj4fA0LQxHkWhpauqJciZ9GTdz6VK7IN@0zdtlO1GjzKLZjLcu@KTsm1VNPjzNtWiDaS8upMvGPFYMNdWiciGXRrXx@fS8JmvTcS4iVZuTiD64KfTUUKh43ZgVu2VKj1x0uon6KJTI8Quevoyq6iTcTFbK@tVimnmqCp0s38gIvRiTid7k2dFVdclXZ@V6vVPTOq1J3Lhk5dsCM6KqN3wjnRkXypME26wsS4nzUmOazZYWs15IHKjpab8TvrqJzcsVodS5psNFbmpe@aRsVaZHFxfGst26LN1UjFvo1lcXUkRcLjLtjC4@5bLGVb1MV/TxsBEZKX2tHZeyKn9RK0XM0jhdnHduk6XMWBBrvbE6bnbkztSUciO6QC2z4@tWT5gXpNWcy0fK7Wt6lK/zZjw9CDfokSj2xnLVWA3Oy6tBY9ob9JPVcyYnPF32M@1oPa@xVwUjUlGWVLeZEaVV/Vpkx7VksXTby6elKyWarQla7bw4W4RCXUmszaMrdnEzKkSkBR9hytXMzZXv@iJU95V9mUxNDVcHVChXOO8Mopc@tSCs6LLIPcWzPn06jSxyU/yLx@WWIuuTqMwkCk3fMG7oneTV1bxnlG7q2Q4vrxK3V@Nx7LZO3cxKhqqHEheFdJKujRn9nBtVSrdxSSlE5plzOZ8sdVathJkvT@VEsTzIXdT1XHPC3yTzg8ZyOR4kLoRaeZymhESuXh/1Bu3eotswakvmKsKPer78eb7yNIB@3G4UQhetTGwwrYfblzllVmsWfCv1plPWspUxm68lprFmPDyhZouLRLphKpKWO79Kxq6nUjmfzg1aWVYVhJsn/pIdc43mkkkYcf26cHOtGT6z2VMjvWEmvLy@6tLtW8OIFiXqdtGJldJjnb/sL8wLI95UQmr1mmGvxUpLjs460lO3po7SE/qydbOie/NVYVEzebMxVqP9eHR8vjCe9NWlfkkluiNOblWyannExy670ipOR1ml2c2KV3z3IsSkW4PilVAozgarljAJjYpP0yLP8UYt3e2dy7HZQvOJ4cSsTDUrnZtB/OmJ6QmVblJKj1v1WskMNTl62m2Uo0/lrmEU@FZJykQkZZrLdM/Hk@ztkmsai9W0GevJ4rKmh5g8tah0r9r8SB0YBeOWH61uCrfK1TQUu6mOxLjZH7MTiS23RSZe0eq@nK8mn/cGy1h7Ksx4sAy165LGZtKjUZWqspP4LLNMGqZyblxWetmLtJROlxOhay0UL46z58VFX2q32pVin1Mjt71sOFbtDZhQP1PJD2qRySBeq8Qj5SzV7C2v62w/l5DYISdnRxfLiJYshzIxuj2vF69HzaFSkbPpzkLMhPmmOo93OFFpCatYnL5ifKNh8kJJM5FajGqZObNVLszDPuWydBWqLZf8TY@bhjnxqWv4@O5quKq2BU6Vh@WnOttsT8tZaTRqxzJ8k6lmGsx0Zcw5rVyjkrmawubKi1lhPmx0GEPLFbVEb1HpZ2s1oaf1w5rYq6YXIjPrdG6vr1tVZXJzPSnW473qqs@Nom1TrMeqC5N6ApOnPSu3Cr1FTjTEUX32pJwvpjdtOtI6n5Rb/ZlvlLztzsLSTZUpVzJtkZuWrgdxs1VZaFcXsijTk1B1QFPzVm21MoW0mq/Mr7oLsb1apaWM8cQuLmmufF7K3Zi@ZL6QzlWbDU6Xq9Xzci7NTeZX8/JN3CesGlf9qDR@uqVqiiKH9NuGHM8wYSPUiuZWWX50zkzPM5PmRTPJamyr2L66umSHMj/h491qLta54jvp9MXl8kLk2rWaVrtsNamqT7m5vW3S1aZcTorlUr2pRksz/arTiXNzNX3NMaXIpDcvLzLzq@m0M0le@LqmwIXVlSCw9blcpoUiyE6CEqazWrZSM5ahp9XoaTDLqTftZFo7j6WzS7E/E2YrJp2b@WijsJj3Y5KWCDW7i3Oxy18NBpf1zDCszbRmLBulLpLildLuZYdXyaVwWSy3C1NTaPR7EclnMNqoeZ1uGS1@KZ3zseGsZXRl6HyiFm1msklDvs0lLnXJxyT4DMV3rrgaXR5GbyoXfXWeXVy1lzmYciRYscZE1aXSnibGSvHSyFx2ni4TiUGrVxxDwdPh7ZCXWr5Mvydci3KFur25bI/ztWmbHl3fXMVrraIvsQrr50@8OjznksvmqsowgpgczErTRVgr84nzxGWVly8WlXpLFAaxRuhaPldWVE6JD5m0yM5nc4X2LaOZRH4gZloVRc@1@GJcUGscTS86t2a1c5O4DJ0z10xjMmdCxtWcZsSuIi27lW431KcyM@NS6zTYWd5XNNPdxqjOn8t0pVMvrdRlOR8yWulKVryczpdaeSnp4Vu@fJ6Va7zEglkSjQ2aemu8ysx6VEdclLOZRPw2VAQJMgw5Oe9GOIE3tMFiRJevpkV5MZqO27pvsqDrvtvuIpoctocGzZfLzUppntej6oUxUqhYjA8VO7oWN@pPk2Upa@aG7ZYcySbbg1612KWvmuJl8jrbuI0L0RpdehKSnUaM4cvRDk@zdXUyM2FE4gdjqrxk@jovCzoXn1afovnp1NdfzqamT7uNn18mOoNxlp3xnC@c7qlP3KJ9ITNSJS4MjGpnPrspdMBCVNqzlkIVblta@FIqio1iu3o1Zmvp@sqkM8kOfxMZdHVWVMRZPWxGL0rCIM6LufzteJQrlp5KTFd8YuasrF9fhwtFloqLvoyp9mW6fa1dK6sQJ6S71cTVvL/KToYVUSiWQjm9W4/1G5ecnIdhVHoqM1q7cF6@7ffkIS2qSrVRZxjqNhbKd27qT@ysf11bNdVFUR9cpGty@EYsKWrtps3mrnW6Es8UrrOj@m12mYjVdLknNAeJpjLxnYdVnksr5RgVF2ZCpt2hW4IUZuOLVY8bCzR72xmPE0V6FTNWdFox5qPEYJXsnU/Yzm1FPW8ux/T5ZHFby9ywU8HHsjVeo67NVS16ft7xXS7PW6WB3CqJPM1NliOjmJkKF/PedSztS2hM05fvt4eLcm2gdfJ0vNdLsI1wuBMxn/q1pXFdodq5cjEczy3NhZgfTyuLRFFLxxrLRes6EhnfjhbVRCNWjy7YmTrOZ7TCIEqrN0ZcWTSLg0JGyItXonG16vETKraaVkqFRN4XFbhurXvLiHn6qdGXzeFAbF7ehBsxmo8Wq7X57W0uTU/i4ihfks9hTJxzV4tlY9Qd966rRlii1GrXV4qtYqvG7XWlr9Q6F1fD3nwQj9f0YnuUnK66Wl2q@7RVq9RTz3O1iZxb3YDAxerJ6Kgl51sd6SZXZ6qUGeuk52CDs5mytBzQpShzKSrMxWJynryZdGLj7ridndW7i/Eo1ohH1amwipudp@hUaMW7F5MGzfe686EvdE6pjdXyJn8d0cuVuVY2a6pwySRC5dtxa5KftnyT7GWhZ2Y7jNYLdcrzqS8bBasgcdVOhiq9y1GmND6/NorXoSTVLEjLaWJ0Hjv31WAwmY6MaqIth@QZ3aHl9nwmjCcMV8lxbX3RaxXK/Uo/lKA1nxSfm5exp4tu7ZYztYhCU8Yy1p9zvmIeLIic1I02fG1TYyYwF2FuZuFLZRAOGcpNo8GbWTU@boWTQqSgtxW1vVBH7ZB0fR4fz3npckRlhFU/IrfqnX5lsZr3k@NIn2vMWunCjdIJZxVtuDB0Npa8DLW5p9pED1dNrVZu8RnlesJx4ty3kDO5K70xo/qDSrrfKTxNxVk7Uk1H0subPhOZ3s5GrLK6yXdDo1ovPRTn9U5kVZ@HM/1zVqlPJG2ih2im2Vby48SiVRQuqYtVXlgOE9eZWjvSuhwlx2F5MG7UmOW4Kon87a0xZUvdQfma7Zei7cx1clwUjbQQbyXFixG9qPSqt7FsX4gwlG9YmtChbJkPX@RvfOYFL0efpBVbMVdJUVlWWlKvMZiltXJ/1JpWMkU6w4Zm54vqJFys0@Epl5kkcpd6V5cpIR9NL1rVq5gxvE2b7YhaC80S2m1NGtyE@rUhx0@YWAJ08FW/d7tspeuZeblbKTaMtDJYCT59fqmclwqFjEIVxU7lyXjiVHGajrSq5e7103VaHzSjPdMosYsngV4ulepFlueX3XTJGFfaFw2lFGcm/cxV/HrYLysttSaFLyk@GR/fxGmlwV9MGSFSS0cKT@1z/qk0i9XVsWLyzfwta1bqoOxK0VZV684nq@yQERfhSP7GqA762i301tGKCk2L9W6/Lo6Uxbx@YbYvw5MGO27P5XFM4TRfJJ@sVjl2EMaTsOiNqkxU@XJg3jQqs0udpoer2FTQzoVLiSqHtEG6VI9dhLjz824u2WInT2UhlLiKTNPzULV@5VOigpYrDSYykx3XR8K1BFOGTqw2umAaFak1uJ1mb5LLBrXq9sSkctGZq5fZ8Tw3no2arUUYplfNdtkwGvUbs1@ahXoXcblXHfabuUL2ms9ynBGvKtl8daxN273JvBiJUqNC@GZ0Fb@QBrFxvCQsu5dTLVm7WJWyw2LE11UuEmaXM@Wnqjx6qvRMs/cUl9qN6wu6k4nzCvO0jJs3ww5tUMXEJH8eEeKr0pCNt5TJbDrtV@uKWlrWrq@AzfFQuHneo9Na57pmtvtFgb8ptsDSv1CFUuPmQmuc3xT7075CyWEQ3yytX56XjcJNbnzLzkv1ZU9ifePq5bwajUfFZM83i04qw2kuGu3EJxeVWSGn6bHFFWj9QW1ZKwv1yhXFTq66@bHvQmTZhH61as8i9bRwE@tdzcV5JJpLL5RhItFiFtcX5/x1oqeV5pPWBTu4pue3ybEx4VpcPc2rYpXKPGnhZW5h5plo/jJWvLkWRrF5Pz8NldLzRqcUM5MVsdOJPM3r87FQKbBiczGbh2qF6rWpRKKL9vXt@BJaIUrxg8V1Pi5cRYQ@I61us3pB7SktLs3QF3Ro3mpf@9SB8lQRfONaqBDWYnlmUeNgZnybmV70Y73WSO6cZ4rJIdWP8Hlf04iVbmNPN09Xkn4z8sUnoHISYn12fQUmSc9sNSOLazHZZVftbKLD9QorNn9JpyPF4jRZCoUuyslylzIa0QlIy9M8dHORk0PXtXYzMvXlKrlFf9i4bdWz86vEbZed1DqN2QWejIVpZi5WR/XWslJYtCQhlh/X82KG8pWu50Y1qYn1XDuv07W@WIiMxsXzwrkwveSni7ziYwal1nL2NJ0IiYsrmRN0pVA3h2k@3E2Mwwu@pKWfLtvUssjlL9hsop3QxxJ/Maq0jJEx62iilI48RRc@sz6qSZfRXL15o4xaw0pF57NXobgh5MaNSey2NVr0ZkK@f0GJZnLGy4vzSsxUMsuCdNO6ur7oN5glX0tcVAr6gunRhacGMzPpVqJRaw56FV0qj2Dg9HVbqpqQQaWYQ/Wa4rRhiZm305f9xMDInjOJ8sWi2pIqPuY6Xx/lQsZM99HDSTWUW6n5i7A4jw/q15cTRs/O@kPfZS1O344y6rxCRc1@uMMZ42RdZLvdNq3l6yvDuEq0er7La5kW6qHbeKa4Ypu9sNafDruJ7uR89tTtXj312o0iNOeNT4g1rp6owfVl0YiLSZ7ttzLZclqdacyFPqmLkUlZ7bZCXdHXXeRK86fQJVMYlXpspTJcrTL8hd5RErlJ7yrLLUetRJsK56tM/zYsaBet3FO3MJyO@Gx5wYdv1KLhu4lUFtNzPRGPsZHkjDPC7cmk7UukZckXDw@Xw1AmP4vl6L5e71D5qi/bUVXoBfXbGFehjUi/IptGK95s5JP1bCFbLF/mb8RyslHibm583etSNp9uxi4uh@PIZZc1MnTmajhqhKhROTvu06aZmEoNqWDkz/XcYng7vp5Me/P4rGx0V8olN5UGE1bktHGnrMRj6ev2U7TKhPNXdP52JSuheHSRpPq82L@g5fr4ppOQ8kW6Kw9hAp0D@R/fXE11XtSNYbIDNb9aKfFsqzpo60V5WAMK5d5U48VJUhoPhfAtVacbiUK8I1@KfLVbn8S7PemmeRGOi9MFzF@7udWlmKOh1VvdxnDK3MTyYLpGIk@lznByPau0jXo0126WaxGq/VTPiWwpXy63b80@W6kyg8LMbMUTxTzLTzLjSn6Z6WVK8wLf6hR9I1@o2ednhXZazrf7nLFY3jJJRk@LIyo2il1lxBxrzqNtUY9kL4bVMCeX1EX1IqFN6rWLUOYify2qY53JXKedT6y9TE6k6HIgptPn7VI3O6DS19ncKNQWDb6u@OYlApYpyNzvfvZRIYKuKwSMmqlSH5HfcLePuTh55@AJcvIEfr1959wJ7OyzfZCAaL9fDbRAOX5XC78hfGwVQvY2g/iXEPDW4snLvcUA6xwnQG74HA90RH79QNzZCHXpOPOajI@S8h4BZMeT7KDgfTDyevIvjGP4Ag1@ByWwibxR5yG88X6VNsIRfM4HPqGTeTjZ2vL0sNvUYAKhyThFBH76Xb/Apyp8BxnJFnC@WvDu29ZnTnbyA3GGppCTRlyBoItktU/FwJh2UVitiePXZzNQ5EAWZ2Ptnd924mg2wcSS5HwPpPhN/@Qu@eA/4lMuJJgSp0yMqT7vjwfqcCYiGWmj3oJfrp4QikZQGMoKfWcd4MnGUjQ5DzcO1wRKMvbhVNb5meS0JHxEFzliER/X6UYosD7g6iPykoAfX45dJ6@kFB1NHCm0DvmY3MUeUkqKOZncKQ8nis/nNX0p08f6PDjiO9Z7ok1tT8Q784G8tU8foSvn1Xr8ywfY91cVUU1V@KHqNhD5AeXtd07IUWROB5pw2nZ/mgm8qerbMSKWJ26y0xFfR@FdYu5FTkl14MylJuCtu/WpBDL@6Xl8@TCNRU5ep@MafviAj9A4sX0ntivwhdKmPVnij6kPhJ94Cxy/Tn98bB8KwyMstx8@kDjJirRoQZLhwcknTiqvaks7s2SBPDp1Od1CeebBe6te/7dAOlA9kMlH/DtVOoBZIBZ7d8ARoCZbo16LKhwuC8p6HxSf4@M9waecoI9OmnPiD4bHckPO3Xk0kURO6YHbKbJByRkYyGufOEFi7yT80htxJThzW0kfRtOJRvafgxa9NkfwT2s@apykr3MGjSn@pWcPYjEzJIdo3AI48IxPg5txprDdNE5bYMc38vIVrg/GVyO/pAIE85yuL7FuxC8fYHx9leT5YP12qweZquVYaZFh5yXV8NpNDYzDp1W7NfcxIn5wJxBFtkRPtlJHkIrr@kbyBJInnDl8I3mIcU@Nt5J1SMa/6PpGsgTJ1juR@9NVSLd2@t8AMLGXJ4jro6k@mpwke6wDPfBRIM@WwvYgn89h7FoEkNUwVnvs5kf20Sjoo9U6lrDtiBf0TyJWFgAWaY/defDzRlpIKj7M22PJxVaZFk/QF/TVwmznSGDxIykJ1C4u33u0gx9tEQD9D1Qpep3uFG619rqiO/IThGFngFsbmBVGP/74HmW2IO7KH/vgSJ/VQtgPd6uGFrc2eKwfnNy0q5VpZWfan8c@OmZbuzk@Ept6OJ0ytFEhVt/a9GtRUvpQBiD@uB2NXZ686NMm5s54QMdr7bHho9Utvs7H0CvpwR5RpEf6UW8T5L@dqxyWe8jJwYjc2ygLfE4Yd/KKncYaOrALfQbQa26@kDN@R2bsXvpzK/tttTkA@kinJrw5sRQtD6bhmU3gHvI4q123dYKF7NB9bMXjH9KUdpFJbyCzztN7BATmKdCARzZHjTtjoqQErXdSQc8zoYifuJhbIM8bNjnK6lv49E/QuTDj7CF7in9bbFcloT2seQW@rjfm19nLLveiepam31@5O@ulZvcnN6YRvZYnInWfYJQ8RgxaH9x0gp6/rof@YZz5smm@HXvH8LytK5xGdyTxW0Tw@Q1Gf1XIdqsQekA7HMckEM3wlSGJHEK4f1DauNY/OjGO26XVt9@0wDBVJ7vpmGYLoZMAhvJ2Lr9tc51tVKd9@uKj6Rg3/o0Vhn/S05IKMNlPqG11jqdzBTJ4b8euj44iHNlOwW@yYwtTdyiTRMe2BTPYyRfkH3EzW0zG/IQ@PVDVvuf/L@76v9JYkv3Pmb@iHV8SSADB5O7e57cbRFTeUXEBYzzGTRBGmQ0wHAZE3k3@9t36VHX3fAHUfe@HPffcOEx3V1VXV1dX13RXGYNJGwwMwUTooEo5CWdlzSoxLyP0hE4bvepeR/kw6@42vVnTr3hdoRcwPrVsgoh39zxttjFtYvaNH3LGWS7HakSozO0DHFYU7aO20u9R25pAr5Y2MhofMck4cqXW87wSJ9SDW2kPcTAUwyFb6x0X7@1AoM4ebbSj@JY8Br@WeBkkhqeObvlnfOvib/sF2MR20M0pyOy2pWZnxwUaK/C//rm@tjENxxu3/nDDGz6QUX07d9aVN5REa1tqOrnL/46DwuXG0WetTfhcNh9CJDGhkQK2wtCbZVCHLGdEEXWzjsSk40OLJQdRiPnceN976JLVLxFbRkH4yP/OabNQLExHk4BLNCKOXad@@j@jeKpFvkWkdwyanB2GE9XJ4H6BvJ3LWcl8SQykEkIsZ2MgrtGSFa771XUxfiBUnye9vnHCgtfu9EAEZO@nbKdouFiSfzmhGXrEWgMrcHmFHvsSZWLEZ0eBgq2TcM6/qfv4XcKDvOEjrpB7vU9x@EAwSvpBMIKQ4ygo2u8QA4Txr5qtg2qjUdDJa@TEOk65yzlmXBHkgHWcfcEe48VpdYQLlEF5hc4CtuDbjYCz/mUeAa1mE6bCDOwUXiEeofQgX@JfC92w9bNSnVnC1530rxC8LOqoHiOyo8C7qFkm1ixvmpnKMVa8epYb7U4HgSBOvUFAFFe8fp@IFl68itiBR3DE4H9v8YfXwHljiZfy/EJ5PlFekHIhKqpV6PTGUaWteCV3/c@o3i/lRtVyC7h2FXW6dsbRpQrBOEb39lN1wwJt0vyo8p4dSpFKW7CTKMjHSv6@ZPSlZC3Rxgq4Lb@Wci3fm3rkLZWJup@S@PHX0QPkcQwGfWUxJaWFod//Q9yPtoQ1rEJYJWmO8Waxk0mpHSJaneRJTZAQ87Td242gvC8ZjcNzxt3b@eQWtEvqj0yaDMm6tjCxlsyRGJcY53tm3COvJISHi9diIBgmBE2ZmbtnGs9143kMLGqtGbSOiRSanODUtfQU38Wx7p/4x0z2JHGm3vrywldC@aN0Xm5aJBnESnfNXc6mpDaZjKeevNSdemIViXDP0xCXK4mzADvQTg@awuL05D7IXTAddtesnogrCqMpFvhuSzSnowolI76rhhCFv5x/brxzjtoDsgr73qMqw6Zuc0B@J3HZZuKFk5DmgEcdHKtwOhr1fR3XTc34Oof0s7T5Gy4jRBBjRkPBqeGCqNTP4UlfjqFGBVUH5BnuGUYF4fQeCafhCUbuZFKtdz6BnBSc8nDOkYk5DNqmXHnx1BRxXKGA@7TtixEhIyezhz0PsNIKjrlYJF29k/k9nJAJRB0POOYhQq1uOc7fpn7nR@VIbRaLfy0VP5RiLDOu6mLhw0dVi5lIpmCzWCoWfyt9dJxKMJrL1cZMJwtYH/MAmFMnWOg/k2x6D8ht7JRpxeCKIZn@oTd@8LoFx2l4XfYB306ZIxDlaehJFGWO84o3ZFsh3j2Zu4Mwp2jb1YN6wV@szxK7tsOBNXIO7hCNvPHAn8hNo@DB74KB5t7UXdDvBzN2ROPKkvADjQbehJjyLquSJHFcWk0L2y4cLpa4gdQOHMDvNnjgONKaDWSn@gi/zxeAHARRBIQ4MsnfHqOE8HX6bX8AcVpCAKIsRRwwBFDXutOO9yQNDhPxb9KgdMe6QWeKyLxtMzIbpP0Cnis03b2xT9o3YjCPCjeL0U4D3DquNVWzfti6LDeqip7PG/XPtYPqgdq/Uq3jqqrUz684Q5c6rp@Qdmmq8tkBvT1rNWr7F606vXDLTWrpcoFTPrtS1S/njWqzqeoNVTs9P6kRNALfKJ@1atVmTtXOKicXtFgf5RRBUGf1ljqpndZaVK1VzzFW08yJ2qn6oTqtNirH9LO8Xzupta4Y42GtdQZkh4StrM7LjVatcnFSbqjzi8Z5vVlV6JhzUGtWTsq10@pBgfATTlX9XD1rqeZx@eQk1dH65Vm1AeITvdyvEpXl/ZMqY@J@HtQa1UoLHYqeKsQ8IvAkp5rn1UoND9UvVepOuXGV00Cb1b9dUCUqVAfl0/IRdc7JPMMVGpfKRaN6CqKJE82L/War1rpoVdVRvX7AvG5WG59rlWpzWzkn9SYz7KJZzSlk3GTUBIO4ReX0vH/RrDHfamctWjMuzlu1@lmWBvmSGENUlqnpATO4fia9JSbVG1eACj7wAOTU5XGV3jfAU@ZWGVxoEtcqrXg1QkhMbMW7qc6qRye1o@pZpYriOsBc1prVLA1YrYkKBBN4L8uE9IJ7jXEiuuSRhNUxkpvj4VS1Q1U@@FwD5bo2SUCzpqWF2VY51jynubzhLP3k9uQHvMWvfNoV8nSQ@Er9oEoWn6SGcaP3F7To/J78eJcoo4XGFtJP/RWU16pvXe92ev/NH94F2JrbZvIFexDe55AgKYt8p1@dJzI56w/l3GB9/du3z@VvtM9tfvuWzb2kZYKM51roKKxP1crqPvaDdpe3@QnfUpxRe290rPecBF6O@1reWOdDVm1sdD3dDJcXAdi4iXRSAgLWhWbkW43toYqh5E/MSV8RZ8xIO4vM580gpH@GP6MfsjbEXpBylnMLGxvYwzIZyHyiLP2EhJOC6MwgfA7Av2OUhdDzftxninF02PJrB1XWtOG6E9oG3meyzzS/9e5TzfPp9kws7pqysWLCwZsw7RDMgH9plik9LoUx9ywjrj3@kzXUMCIyCrOCii@y6tMnmTfSHPFFxVeY3bahxDkdyGn5S@0Sm7ni5sft1Ptj@17mFm6dI7cNrXfX3O6G/xzfSAWaYD62X8QSfy6fVDc2Ym3IKmN70lZGrPoeKs38Lq2pWKp7Hi/riJAv4YLj7WkxHvuPcepJDR81yqf7F4eHpDlB7cfff/vrX7YdHXF/PPmSk79XwIOklsxdsqJnPplpXBSbJRWyew4XkuXEsvtg9FARCSXNoPHLNpm0NnKm2AiSX0PcQOhuiAwDQyTZcJEkYOwq3M/31hwjr0tnphaATKKrWfRm0H5kC79NphLLQEeiZPbnPGqP@Aew7fQ3U9x2SAuQFjFvMJrMSXJpc8F6zz00AQd4b8PXilGl4Bo5HrXNGSRhDHQmR2HAHXz@pWU7Nopk12KgMV952LklEbGWpsIkaeGUS4TiPAjNDJaXPr35ouWNHq90ciAUIdVDedIkNh7alnmTvEd8znpiaMg3e7s0RG/eWEw7Co7UrCZK/P/J1DHx2cCkyIEGlQJsTh5ZPtsSdkJ/eptVf4qkIqo34GxridW/SXKXdUdD2TYh0fVvk0FGCawooQy/mlkcjqlyZapYdibY9P/iB8P/D/JkCfwd2nAS9IhbrIf94dR7IScZqvCKdq/MFH9mTozFjqlF3Iy/uorA/IoPTM92TB/De5QPS8QCPTpz8@JKUoplljAAQg6/Rnz@IoAvT@Jem3ZOn3juvpIv/eNhZzDKmIRcZqlYgHuTY5srZ47I4UdWPuEXVQzdCfKrfOI4j6wzsOEiLXY7V69DV2C8L7HOQac33rHTw85yFk2woWRmeCRORT21zOR/1CeMolWma0p/kSm6OtmX/RyCnEIJhW@@gBgFwmef4h3WbCOceyB0ab8R6YW9/Eqv4shXSSqQ12XV4vAcYfuO98xYinQsDQTtAErAed3VOZtuvckMy0VfoHMMkQiayrzmMCZAon2R1owwyjdbIK7zIjuz1LObEvJqqb8Y/hgil7InLi5To5DIABUPwVpQp21OBtV/Wb/dCPl7sHUvib825LgqHfleCdcc79wJC3b6r8OII2RxzmBd0joUcand@YGXrpFRf5b3H@kP48rrnpucRrRn4Ix1y4z@Xys3BJCV1BlY5X4dWifSlixku6@N@YInmbv26QpP2s@8S50i4ugNDsxqMwgkw27CIc3F2cb0JcLq4PDpFllOs1nhtj0dtId37YHfn/Op038EveFGOJyGo8Jo7rium/QGIhA4QqQQ7RNPXfrDbjAL1T5NBziSmmcXzfOk4y/m@aqI50up/yEcap8xOwvg7xAzKQzuJjQ03raa6@Ti48jdw35C7Wlht9YcLxCYaswCRHgH1jI@OrtQR97QG5M9eM5nLtWJ3/GGpD7ImOJTmGFPNA2qHwJ7U2NXh7Bd2LOzrTyfnTrWt@doBBpaDqKVoalIBI91WkX45uck6jGfYGGxw1G/usap1AtGOhoQnKYwNsXFeTft5xzkbrystY6xGZeNOftmaFkzvj74EsV0Goizljozbg8nc2KKk3beENnP@W4KioMBEURnNTt5UzdALvYu3H79kLqKzPBaC/AKQlPV8x@QLI7dcC8ZIz5nq91mEd@2dXzFnKSvM6ojMXpONHo55Awt5NRv/61aHmRXnffbHdphqeYUzT98IDtwPwgnqHpaVqq4WSqV8qUPcNFeNMsFngj432QQc5za6Xm90SJG6hD5RjDsmgnmc9IuOY1F7MgjdRf1/jsUsqlPGnPzOzMPJriJ4@tuyxcLd8ulse@04e6lHoZJc5hdsnDJB2NOHIZoUCRCielIWBH0ACn6WEkCUwx6jlOX6eRjsrRYOjmaHzf4Dtr6JFd9fA/9zo35HSkA75HfUasx7wy6Ouw9jcnAG1jq/YlZ3dtSwUnnPLMME18qCcfb3FtYScS9bBxO18MZiRDZAwbhQ2dMuqX9QCKHIywmJBbJDOumrO1N@9bv@zQHiK5OL8CCI@rKDAS7IOIZ0RwecZtrBwsS07IkWwHNrm4wsFWFKsexweD0@1E47wRq/Z622dhphSPP63KmhOlIUgGgvECzvE8rh4SJ24pyBDjrRT43OSZlg5QspPumfcSORay/Wxlzx/SGpMqEF2z1sK0XQNSj5oQnKTK2ZZbssHMK33mzPOxtEgi0zYIRKwL9EYhRDh@liCoabxYIfmJxySEcVZ/HOx0HEA05GVE4ShYAlnzV9ZIFBjz6rh8XKoiQ7loCUiEGDTESJ0ueEz6w5A/0F@dOETQtI32kzs2zlpmHPlJoim8gUPcB/kXlguGYfCP0@BvhQuDCR4TkJXjpmqXFmlTLJhCJ1dxcAjO/FOaH5TDzGqb@WFkbPnDANrRisZBeSDTogPQjGBF1/ygwqpfDyvUD@cBke3/fD26Rt4k0BWHDn3kuGtj4a96BJRgdL5Uggsl8UzumS5p0fbfJ2C5qh@aHt6d2jMdi7@tQBkoX7Mpc4phlitcunk78iH/0jOJHN5G8ClZHKnsVyJO3pLsB1tUg9Rt3S0UzEydx4vU15mSTQaJJKdVEE5dscptosulEkUpTo4sWUP34m@yZsUv4VBKPgNq1A1R0Bu1H2d0UOQAdu2mQMjIREW/zRgsIKl53lI1ph@o3ThSiOfHZXnCYn3wEj098u//lcsqrYjLfwaM5usdqgGslyuccBnyY0R3KajbwDxv@OWuI0f3a4SbDmKayHZYCJ9HtMe5qZeJYsltqfdSWr4aoFWJhi6O@Zh7gK71L/71TGY0gHydWKiGsrlaFxHgOvXxNW1kZFqMHi060MvOvmIKjEXREf/ORMVkGMpnEvDKa28KUxwXdTaDwXsAxJkfif4Zk18lbrCgx1dCEwYc0ptrI8x5pe8bfmBkErz/WY61fSkxjqz008dcR5huzaiR7sbJ2eilZVie2qlguPFXZMNvyaWXl1asNsw4@BOg7qR5j3QmcxJp1Zgl@GwrL2ErxJxzsNOj4oqGSbIspXWmbW6KAk0NuiMuleuXEQpnrHqaXESexciaEJBP7hTTt6rUkshNAWSfRCvxfNeA47hif2CvrlaSeHvZVEmFhmXF/SixsZTPuT4mFVI4N@9NiYXIZWtZy@7RcJEZCWIBDiXrHwD6luA4yBY/xWo@pWkzQ/CYey9zrZ5ZQG9Oq2tfpLJhKlkU6dUkSB/95lIFZ14FGE@JIzLu2o3ET9ZbWuM4Pr2sjMuve2y3SnptcEmQ004kI0GmDgcfoJouU2bYBaWxxguk980DObnJE@7eyYeE9KLJ23feSt3sTYM2qUswuGpQmen9E/M5S4vOLWRSiLdbWYn54e7pMU40DT8G4i9qus@SLr/MMVe9jVCV7FxuhJItXQMq/CFL@BZA2YpD0xP5A6yU/ro@Rp857DsTXr4sw@M/faSOlYZCm7fpwYmMfPGvPn4O5RsbWOp@pa8upMtsgspOfg/FHGgbnBe3Zr3H6Za8Nr9v/euMgnZVjJWeTsrKEIkvV@iJZOZDFWpv3u7qeMZV4b1v4cdvz7U5g/fmRljjGujGOEvfsR6D1ZFR9Cyya/6UV/MvFhjU5H4TwhBuGrGXn35wOBTBCPExyVcw2iCmy5D5UFyQZ8XRpWvnxbjUd/RgJT1c2yz7bk0/i8Ik5nUrUNdFYCYkzW7hIOZnVyui3ZduzZ/GvL8U/CkZk49wtJYDrD@DHF6dUSqVHpmlqa/2itWzperbYr7jdlspN8vJJ/mah65vUdVxMp0k99GZ69X8Ksu6LGYH/gyV/bWRkBZGvlxKJD@1t7dxSw@ng1hs7L5nq0qKAP7JHWi25jrO@rsod2jLryPjwinU4fZ@nUcIMhiCEajrC95pQDndicsNH5okAp@t2g9mQaxdcoGAf7cBrD3WofL1g3o/x/cLWzSF9Jy53MQZ/2CFGh17M/fldclJ3PV2CE8lPsHV7@dhDqoFTU5GLMGmyxNbMzJN7Wnm7wsCxVg3X2kobKkZ28DH0nVjm2l4iwzy73AX2EuvpKYOIhHgVSr3hTYF@Wka3VjNzOrKstEPzAlYuM7esl/sF5tb8pebWf4CT6QF1Ys/aetAL7NazSi29yXf@BQ)

Languages that are not in the driver:

- Japt (7) [online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4).
- 05AB1E (26) [local](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/ed8c855aeb4cca47fc63e4f0094e22e4b4f1a122)
- Moorhens (60) [local](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wheatwizard/Moorhen/ac540e857ec546442a21e0a242c5b184b8504c24/moorhens.py). Use moorhens.py from the v2.0-dev branch.
- Objeck (83) [local](http://www.objeck.org/downloads/)
- RunR (90) [local](http://www.mediafire.com/?ukd008kyd945fy0)
- Emotinomicon (94) [online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html)
- EmojiCoder (96) [online](http://sarahnathanson.github.io/EmojiCoder/)
- Cubically (97) [local](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/tree/c55e749a9c999a27d3a287ee67f400e610fb8183)
- Paintfuck (104) [online](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/esoteric/paintfuck/paintfuck-canvas.php?xsize=9&ysize=9#) (9x9 grid, origin at top-left)
- Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 (108 and 110) installed locally using [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- ImageFuck (119) [local](https://github.com/DylanMeeus/ImageF-ck)
- Braincopter (121) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/braincopter/braincopter.zip)
- Mycelium (123) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/mycelium)
- Deltaplex (127) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/deltaplex/src.zip)
- Brainloller (129) [local](http://lodev.org/esolangs/brainloller/brainloller.zip)
- Extended Brainloller (131) [local](https://github.com/GReaperEx/Brainfunk)
- Wierd (136) [online](http://catseye.tc/installation/Wierd_(John_Colagioia))
- Gaot++ (140) [local](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)
- Floater (141) [local](https://github.com/Zom-B/Floater)
- BitChanger (142) [local](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/tree/master/bitchanger/impl)

### Explanation

BitChanger is a language formed out of a goal of brainfuck instruction minimisation. To this end cells are only 1 bit making `-` unnecessary, `>` has been combined with `+` to form the instruction `}`, and IO is memory mapped. The data pointer starts in cell 16. Cell 8-15 hold the bits used for IO. Cell 7 needs to be set to do output. Changing the state of cell 5 causes IO to be performed.

In the polyglot the loop already existing for brainbool is entered twice because of the `}}` that exists for agony. The `<` inside the loop causes it to exit after 2 iterations. The rest of the loops are skipped until the one enclosing the PATH code.

```
$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{^{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]
```

All of the `{` are for Japt to cancel the `}` in The BitChanger. The `}` allows us to enter the loop. The code inside the loop sets the bits into the correct form to print `1` with a leftward pass ending at the IO bit is position 5. Then we set them into the correct position for `4` with a rightward pass before moving left to hit the IO bit in position 5 again. We do another rightward pass to set the bits for `2` before moving back to cell 5 to print. We leave the loop with the cell pointer on cell 5. `}<}` is equivalent to `>` in boolfuck and `<}` is `+`.

Answer (score 4):

## 145. [MiLambda](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MiLambda), 6254 bytes

````html
#16  "?63(o?23!*# #@"/*"r"{\D v'[af2.q]PkPPX)\(9 9'#CO"14"^  */
#/*0|7//```"`  [>.>.])[-'][(  >77*,68*,@'1   #  1011)(22)/ \S \7aa*+42@n;EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ iiipsddpsdoh k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz( coding=utf8␉␉␉␉1P''53'S^'????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!) (qx
#>c#z#111#y#y#y#_#11111xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx/112\n␉
# 36!@␉`  e++++++::@    / "78"oo@     h#115 o# doxe b  x-----
#xTaTaTa TbTbTbRtRtRtVkVkVkRcRcRcBkBkBkLzLzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#~==+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.._+++++++.
#`<`============================================================     x
#<<<#>>]}}+-[.^;+;;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]+-+<[<<.>>x>-]>[
#{
#x}
#2""/*\*
#=x<R+++++[D>+++++++q       L+++<-][PLACET,2<-#2FAC,2SUB#1<-#52FAC,2SUB#2<-#32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs]_>@@+.---@._+>][
#x%+>+=ttt Z_*.                              _         _              _
#D>xU/-<+++L    _
#R+.----\   \).>]|
#[#[(?2?20l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOxx4O6O@ 0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11MoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l111111^_0    )0\\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq{}26q[puts 59][exit]" ,'_\[999'];#/s\\/;print"24";exit}}__DATA__/
###x<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#d>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.!\
'(wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWWW\WWWWwWWWWwWWWWW/WW\wWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW/WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwx                  (([5]{})))␉\';';print(( eval("1\x2f 2") and 9or 13<< (65)>>65or 68)-(0 and eval("\"ppp\".bytes.class==Array and 4or(\"ar_\"[2]==95 and 5-96 or-93)"))^1<<(65)>>62) or"'x"or' {}{}{}{}{}{}{}({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})5){}x{(x<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)wWW no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no os sp '#}#(prin 45)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)((("3'3)))"'a'[[@*3*74[?]*]*(<*.*\>]xxxxxxxxxxxxx)'# \\
__DATA__=1#"'x"
#.;R"12"'
###;console.log 39;              '_(*****************819+*+@[*99[?]*]***|!  )'
#\\
""""#\
' ( <><        (         x)>  ){ ({}[()]  )}{\';      a=$(printf \\x00    ) ;b=${#a};#\\
" }"';           ((   ( (';case "{"$ar[1]"}"${b} in *1)echo 54;;*4)echo 78;;*1*) echo 50;;*) echo 58;;esac;exit;#(((('))))#\
=begin
#p             +555/2+55x%6E2x
;set print "-";print 89;exit# ss9
utpb now 70 dollar off!
utpb has been selling out worldwide!
#9999 9seeeemPaeueewuuweeeeeeeeeeCis:aj (japppppp⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희
♈
♈♈ +-------+
♉♈ |$0011 \|
♈♈ |/1000 /|
♈♉ |\ 0011\|
♈|/01 00/|
♉♈ |\ 0011\|
♈|@ 0110/|
♈|       |
♈+-------+
♉
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋
1  1  ! !
2   !    !
1      !!
1  x*
53  +
1  x*
51  +
1  x*
34  +
15  +                    ?   ?@             !
1   *                   ?@    ?
1   !                     +   *
1                       ?  !  ?
1     !                  ? @ ?
x  x    xx   x  x
x xx  xxxxx  xxx x
x xx x x    x x
x  xx  x    x x   x  x
x x    x   x  x   xxx x
x x    x   x  x  x x
 x x   x  x   x  x x x
 x x   x  x   x x  x xx
x   x  x x      x  xx  x
x   x    x    xx   x
x    x xx     xx
x    x xx     x
 xxxx  x

7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
You can see an x here.<<11
>SET x TO 120.
>X x. PPQ
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #s""oLz
More 91 of thiset of re9 red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up ssswwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWW baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
How much is it*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449, 12597
#endif//*
#1"" //*
#include<stdio.h>
#define␉ x(d)␉#d
#define u8 "38\0 "//"16
char*x="24 10 31 1 "
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int  y(){puts ( sizeof (0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x( 0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77" );"21015""6 27""Zingeg-' ?";return 2;}int z=0;int   q(int a,int b){return b;}main(){q(z+=1, z)?puts("124"):  y();}//<*/
#1""/*/
>main=putStr"128"
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//* --... ...--
/*/
p=sizeof("9( 999fi 99\"  ) ;print'(''72'')';end! "           );main( ){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return(9-9+9 -9);}
#if 0
#endif//* rk:start | print: "69" rk:end 9        @,-1,:*b5<>␌
print 61
#}
disp 49 ;9;
#{
}{}<>       K y7g+H           ;
$'main'3x            #     $  |
#-3o4o#$$$
#<T>"3"O._</+++++++>/+++<-\>;4=C+++.---.\_<!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.-.>@
#<<<#>>>  /                  44
reg end="";print(85);reg s#+++;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-.
=end
;"""#"#pxxxcl y"78" \++++>/<~#class P{       function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();} }
#}S9^7^8^MUOUOF@0:8:8\\     @,,1'1'<>   _     @125iRE
#s|)o51~nJ;#:p'34'3  \=#print(17)#>27.say#]# print(47  ) #]#echo 21 #fWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWwvm>++++
#s8␛dggi2␛M`|$//''  1$>{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++.._#]6~-<~-<~-<<<~-COprint("65")#asss^_^_# 
#9 "25"   +/ ppppppp           (x*n^*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*<>e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e)*///Q222999686#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKlhj4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZkvayn5cfxoShSokSRNEk99/FFD2bQSXeCmUyn07jpTvre28lgGph8aGRmgAQJMMDka5Afcb42BnP/wZ1VReply977dIe2yGLVqlWrVq1ataq4WOxxxvD3vz/CB6qp8nIgqyYyBcNEfV2aCbofpZboMycZ4UCQojBUUh9MJ4JiGqfUEWIRkhRe6sM9MtWxoEgrQYf4AEKarg50boLMIWciweA5TTCQOjW1qYlU8XC2IELZiTqSfDjnRFIGAGYKuqYLJkkPIdRSZG7S63MvUsIvCtR0SDdQRpB/nPxoIl6dTDilbwBkBKFMNZUtJV9giCJUVnVDwHh4wTBUHBlDaJEV@BegcQDldEktJSuXL5JYBl0C6ZwmCwvE9QxT53hTUhWcxKJGpdWo7eUgLK3pan/K4@qaQwGSMYtESRYMioeqXCDNbhg/DqAjpAtc3wKjRFVHOAuajGUkIV7TUE/mhn4eyRLA5pgYEjBH0QrS5aGBFtoEMBjqRNilw0CKIPSRoQm8JEo8KR0JC1NQDCDe8COJH6O5JMuoL8iQYUsS7wVkaGrsRFkE@Km@SiE4eO1FBTZ3xwLAKMKaCYIGTMVMUHEbAEfWvJjrnKYBkcDEBhBuShMQJcl0GkjgDAkLK2QxBKVP@KdtxFhFnLJbSzSTOMQBvVOd4DYEHbeNn@BFQ0EXACW3ESTXXJdMYAFmbxLVBE5HTV0Q3PsivVckFKbiEkxcET9pvvNzZ7aac0IzWjn8nGZSR3qweV2kOORPoOPHM/glHI4zKlvJoC/H9zhsSTA0taa7ODdK/BIZ9P29AL8F26MH@jMFWCngioxoVTNpzqcBgT4TCKQ5HMQh3yzg1@SdgtH5i7bYES4Lqg@tgQoKantJzfipruNeumUqN4ZKy6oyAH5CZfWpgvmhoAgDTcCr0Mm8SJgB11TFaiN1TjjcHErQaAZukp1@YekawlDQNiB7NkfX5RqqPCVwkNMwsQACVyArxlgQURuJnCTjLJCOUVlU64IxlU2cZ6r0ccuDLhH6frQmg1f7GGiizqA4DpCSCOhLk50eSIgCYGgIlVQVJ/30T/@iPxgAniTPq3rfFtc26qs80YocIRZUDcICqyqcTMgCOC8u3coOBcw4WepzJi5eWdpFECJIqXN1KveRCgXqcwm61pCbQXcURYE3BUvILUXqRRNubOkNyZJcqPiE60HDkgJI2aTaPvQ5Da3EC9QRkRnfZGqKMeTTsshp0N@7Pp26Pn28F4A4t999ckzTgzMQOP8JiYI753uS007uKTrD5AxV6lPa0hyqSgD5eOTgE6omKC7nHg6n16n3nG4/1mcu95mU4P2ipPRdTpDxFJTrdJ/xCf5OOn04e5F7t0TAMsdYcG8VXLzbQYHGIX1iRk84SfFrS9T22aGdNNV4xBzHyf6daMyXl3EzK@KIjCNYLFUsH6CG/IYsCJqL8bNurCUw3MFq44RDFX2Bw67wqfTgcR45PbtVJxigpnsVxX21KalYa8nacAo6GpiiGBpobx2LLs@B8BhYiZswmHtRj4g10fygWIhKnAtOXUA90KNrMSI90upxOL8P60kbw7YHreH2O7TQ3@nPoAugS5vGK6Usq3MomNCGhy/QIAounBtAE0Fmq0JJq0JWiSRmv2pjBfQKxtYTUMzXk6Av4F4Hqt0W/Z06AngwYMEANquv7KigCbcELLw1JG77DZJE6FIT0BL6EvECVj2ggwRrXMGFTEk3NMCMwQYN4wuEw/td7VVPM3U66bsFXb2i3@1QuPK7fQrrGyQKcyRzymDKDbAlpUAWjucFzbT1FdTEMEEjvRx2SKTPHkP9xpA6/vyybDKW2KPrThlY11utZ4@IHFYyti3lk0GnIs62BlFf0kE7ycuXpQPA7EXhjh8wyB4BPzjeIGFtCICQCQuBn5qg3ECQ50OJH4LsYuoUSz1aY9HL4iFqt3RQ8D5xUzQmhr34LkD56U0UJuNNFD7coq/xwBiLUV3sRZDG3414HzNnTA4gVjckwniwE@unOT/I3ldwTlRFPYAUGLlBi0H2U6x2AIOsgY1BGL/W1hfprBsLcdNE0GagPaDng/wNTVMzTmG4kMzhtOcHSaGb@rJgVhUsLLSpLyVTtcI9We2Bejagf9LrEmh@2pMWLypE4jZtODKoGdhhooESMIA/TUHqXE7RAMVJ4tMYeCfJQRQ4QWGdHQBIgPzAKJdoEJWcA6XSWCq8y@EnXckPnc7hRQ7ccR1uCOBcG76k1QnWQqhD7ANs8KV00FwiaCtb9xPVzx0c8TZjADHvnE7/SJUU1xfnx48fnafOC9DwHz9@gtA5Dn3CIQ@EPpGQj4QwnB@HSA4vCeHUO5IDxz04n@/WmBfuB9xsCzw6rSTNxd2dngYfvNwda18D@OoGVQeaDaB9@AJ4nO5EAgfdbsfFHCrq74lW7esWZ/tEGuqCMqCEhabqJqpUM9nHWrKZTzjoqaHTstSjFRhfHyfQg2Eu4ziQHyYl6@wQrKuqmSANhuMJdA6A7DkcZapT6PMw/5Amklkgsx9ZwYK9bbR1ahrK3SKoSYJJ2aPRVtbxRGjbNlAPAl/YnROJujrZaDiDEvihihzHQQe25femqXjYt1NDOHVqT1J34qM4foInmH6eGvA88qnW7SbSBoxhQDzp9MNkjhp4PBiSTEI3kTZknKDEE1G/3ltHfmGZZxy/mYXujCO7GA@lv51pg5wlyA1lami4coRnB6bTNnwEA/fVniAvIiGfIIt@c7HyY3URCVHWBfn6b0EcyEstVocyUCb0fd9CfJHA6ZRFYRPGsBJMWVBJMsjqw24zU5sOck85rA4c3B@dHNuUwNaUPGz/OnaxEGEGARmrWF1uQ49g7IX3UMD0/XVOUTKG5LQH@oqi1ykktzHpieR0AODUtqmgS@AJPmZJEU8PsVmnqkgR5gSMjA4EGbBKUji6Ti54nDhEz/6It0dMTxCnMGWke5KCw18B88VjBFLs9aS3QIEvmPT19QCYPu0dYhsI1/CVUYT2GG9OdVMW@vb1v/xBHxrgdfMMuSVMdfjxJvAIfMNN5RPfbC07K74hp8MtS2BGU1niCBtI6GsoeQ5PRzl5EziMGqtk5PMNOR0ad7luXBBOfILh9R05syjXBXnaF9bXw4UQFu@bXlZuRZqQGsEV25FkHH0j@wvD0cqPp/O6rHJ9gsVaZpGEbWtb7SIsuAFUjt7RSKAhv4HOtX2HtusqYMiYU@uMl1K@1q6Shn@HuXK6L2RMmOuxAkxDuZ70Bh8xGZG3JNvqMNj08IkyN7aCjzh4uLJWdXRpMACTy76@BQb2NUyBNI4X6Dm5vCMW68EAkYGeew@nLlvnt0DWi8KbwFuAUFWZnH6O8BFx4KGHYNnBC5q@HTZJLxgrc70lNtGGP1@KcIFklAUlk@A9HiaIB9zNDHi7dKppb@fHFgLJH48fzm2tshIEvCqKgvC1ngujjzThZF@gvxN8UxGvTdpt6ADoiJtxYOzKnAFCYtpsFmbQLOT0nuDiAYXH4rINvSO2W3LWCx1vzZW3eTSJV2XJ0Ehzr2/e0ogvZxlbNHgdnZy2WfHda/72wbDHg7VvEzrcqVXexPPVN@ToG5SUNVXEk/EdwfCrb/GOV@f496aZMFRngnU@PHCtDlL1DSrIJxPJgMni6@x9/mviihc@yekwF8cHqTJ5@WD8KSqrqj4UFAMF/Aw2cxSyWg/Dtixbc9dmofq2TBuSrBqoQc7v8QImBIZhnQ9L8y7bJE7x8UOrj23Ch7MdJIoMcihJzm80LicPVDkSG9AcnN6UgKkuYk1vX79Vw200FMt@VUNtjB5VYe3rm6p9DP9fEw6yDqvj5Ymd4Du21CF1Zk9r364gzAvwmuPhyuWYGMnpp61Z3FsNoPPDObdcX/8Oo8db3F2PHtqSmMxg0@EM8RgETN0yo/8upYXeL63/bTrqFdro1yqx07hjWQCNTc6vmhQFGPZn5mAZ5ts1lihPhalwUINUeyMBxOY93fHtRDF2NY7tdQ8amIcf0W6gVvaE8JuoxuM5vntX4XCyBJ38q9bMQVWjgZ2t4Ql0DQI1HHidcaBMtb3G3eFdfarU3@fcUFv3bLW/RyRO@bkaKfZ1m2nPFDcE8nvLbM9OVJj2qhOwIZRvaH8bKVkiss57iEnMFvNIwqtV@rt4T9FmHRPsV7BHoFWlseHDS17fpngCb83XCXA8DjMyRTCX@PwWtw8p0p6qyj@ndUCf9iVspoHxiX0VvtZKr2wfe0kbbVcmDLzK0RPfWpOwxhp78gjcwxPlNxu6BlUyyeDwLa38ag3wnVFrZ0Xwa3NIGLHJwo@h8@vwW/TWcedm/TF/9F2C16ti9DrwHrK4P/gt9pG2NnrJgitepLWWZbfOFkcv9I@2BE5JfZ/BD4WJQG7fsfi5/mhqrC9vAi1U/DuQ7KfJkukb@TQJOryCz3tLwDsmkakqgkGbnD4Q8FxFFjiwRq3Yt5TseiX2IHMLE24g5L4qWdtlB/ywk9elveDhBYhT6/kDD9m@okasaaCqjIWlsb4eNpaXPLTndPIutkOdnMerm1/t1X764OrzV2w@ZagOlaEw1EnP2Ny91TdAIk3LDeu9SgD9Q84Y46e7tkLSzBLyPaGd2d7Q2OWzrMryt/AZq0ZLUarq4SXYLPav6kPWn4V3yfUgwb58dbUORnDCLjKUv9WLhsIUBipDNVVN8JG7t0BlvNZjnQ@vKheqTgN1JEHv45pgqZxA0VJPFtBcAhJGxu5zgsPrSD1Z5bArwTu2PHBmff2WlSle1Q/bdJecaoKZ@v7YmyP0fG2ETkkmfuw/@ArgXvP0BM5UpDFt93T79rBE7@tdUjUJ@TI42i9LwAx96cetnNhNb@BL4XAfl0q2I@Xb1NqP7IiL18YLwPDavmkQJ@m2J5Kxcfc7Kii8LhCfgPUzYnSEPRWmk6nMmaruRwTO5eI8HrebsjLhdYKBAmBrKOJwhb0wLF8uA8mSYRJYSUR3d@j4y@KUOWWfUQI5Th3o4cHCSvwBsguNeErVrax3x9xD4tjp8zmPnffKKWKcBFSQYdp2EJTbgxMlcrHo3FYdKdyEOH7g8LqmZ5Z3iTEkDlwgDn0Q0BbYHWSNSdUtHwnLEaeJHy7857/u235tMNAYaCIZYKYPFOyLqU6EoTr/ZJVrl57UNA77xWEc8yFePcel@9JJZED3goGVuLOpc9TKNWO2d4ztLQo3NTy87FBhNSo2ebDPlmk1mkVNXxUssbAL3uRaV4pX5elEgU7dN4eGHzWgqwvE@2bzvBRCGEwxdazZ@l5UQH0BL@v2MWFkWJdVdUweBGNK/vNfWz5BkChhEcLhdfHEJXCnRIRNFeKIw/PqFKheI1kJumqDuDCTYWiZYosZhFqw4t2IH3LEWQkk0bd21cHFWO466WQD@bLIiV1asQPAmSS6jpP1y/Yd85D4JZrQwn/5A9r9xeab4xe@aMRweNEa5OwZy9VuchiSt6lO5DheOOxqYedJ4iu4ESrbQdqFw6S51q43E@J3SeROmBPXG/JEW8EjJ3ZoVAzoH3DrJqitTpM4dk0t88zXMFEY@/2CxcNByPLUJC5s2I0EZzleoB/REMuKj0dsmIE7iyEy9lyaJFLrR3PB3aendEboTcmThFnAHwgmSHWOHxPnFySkC30VOxLefX@/CDC@@0U0@0Aba@bc3y9@wQRugHsqjBfH39G4A2UrmS/H/gvmxx8NbokcjmfnmfU0GXr58ZdaoZZtNJPNVgO4@WxV9iin6hNuqymwLGgyx0P3kYmHJrBFlwTj69pjo0E2dwDucqFjDp1j1263e5OwAbVZ7fA5jq3gBgRMqN3cX8l@KL8h7KS/BrA1kyghW4uiGhEkW2acxq4G9a5lC7cL7u5T0NlrjuBn@wdUIeGRAyWASz7g0jfyCL2updWCn0gENOPXGfU@jkMogFdbiNcAmEmbsnB9rXSrcgcr//zfoMYajGt/3xoTHO/WGEO8V2MA3GYjOXLJQqlVz@5nAnHauuODcarjlyxE0rcsx15LulTbiXStmYhdZ9jOYhvdaqCZZBC7D8ubiEcGmESR7kgeKBpYuyCsyPwoKRugyft9UE29pYk1G6h0P3EisTxJfApyHAGz/JuB1oscFIY1Eq@dCUFzzXnQYj9YmY8JHMFsUAecn@8F@qd/@heWw/O9CeE/ssMihP@JFf6exgx67bRp0bhhDWZLu1BDBjE4ccUn3GKnTnjEwiOipEwFJE2AgzPCEAxuEbut7xaP664N/IRGAGZi1Yu1LSlP0B9c2OXulKaxgYEXC/zEEUFY8MQUJR54T1PsgA4DBB0JR0IsDUT6ZmuEPslC6NMshG73KcgaNZO0xA89Hp2fnyOHwXOykIicWYykj7nvg44fNoQeAyxl2SJ3CPJAlm0OSLuws7mOOQ/rxllxl3OyTvRwBmaG1S4wUrlIAEDcOFqx@eGAoVC1WQWNrggLk6jz5drGAgNHIZ5UgvUawhqRDxBZuLGf9EvZ3T7fxn4/O9Ls320GRweDNTDYqeOQ6Nx9j@7Ne@XBdpdHIDC/OSBICoT/@IAP/UZ6kq@9t10vfa9xbdDnhqJin4ccUItcAToQpNmIe6enOGxUQC/uFz8CSugJ0LN4QRqpmpFMZwvFaq3xyvuYQDpfgjmR8@Lcc@/ze@8eNgHnC6lfMzWVoxvlVG7Nyl2qtsuGGGK7dviSzEOlvaT0jdI7lmPB67JJwquCWOZbEZPZuS9HltdfY9@m0juAaevB56tSXe4vz3cP5xf3ytGr4n889GLGkf8ECxeE7g3yWoYTHdA5hbW7RBO/TGf41/53Acf2taON16F1v41@239482re1ol47ZiBHYgDF3RfmNHKVJYp/xsuG1B3P20VRTxoLcLW9IKuWZPKYlK3BfLUq6XfXWqQXZfXbxHajpQbJlWt6Sl5QYJTYGaiS7wFbRAFbU1iiTc/TGMK5nbmA7MpvFxHJnhLMpkBVbF5jNyXyKIVzLrtGmxSGsJE8jXX9GDFsXUKBkWGnV2HUDeYs59xibsF2rgfvucv7Dc0WTJd2FF34ceTRKiNy40rwJ7LAvbzPY8/2E7FaO376yHuw7Up8Kumamg7Mc8I61Ad5mYoMwXkIAYCKk4nACeSS13Ao4SAKqoPMgMfnWsi7qAUl10H/6QfhtL9Q2HRlwYw0rjcXlBJv2DZreMx5/bAhNoJethi1SV@Pr7LmJ/lLL3DMe6O80tKX1i48Isxpw@YOxDvnHdmTrfjlQwQj23bfbv/0nV7rSw40@61W7fnFwohHt8ogv2@E4/7hwaF3UNhXgElNky9BEEYQ13ihNOQa0p83w3kR@TWde9SvIapu5HvAo9nc6Qgj4fMSOBCEvyI5BRJSJLxMpQLvzHmohPQzjjWUPr4spI0dMf6/Q8QJoW40TFeU0iDuYFn424KDE7IckrQwgAMf6eYojnMvTBF1vWYFEvhBQEdoA4mk448GJIOCLwgtUYX36GtNtj2QIur8fip3Rr76jCOQCzOD2gMQHtAza0tTuCv7eMHXMNKDKDSMNWUQKF8vhIUBfqrC2RmAr0TcVMQMt3tXb/F7N2@CUdKOLJIzNtOg0Do/htyWecXWQV75pg@I/Pas2cY93@4xwO/aA/9S/of0H767IvrWE4saTDG3Beu42GC9QRPPJ5j5cR1rGBz5Lvv8HT4@RisnUe/w@9YAJDvWHafgTyDdZQ4Vs6OuXPXcT8ROCE54NbjcX@BDL80aP@XY@6ZPv4OrAkvxOhW73QdG27cHRi/n30G@nAPOaa9IDNfXA7kIO8g4@KPJY8H0@A/fsQE/JK@b3jIuHLfoMnM@8w2cunBZK1G9m2VTUu8eqfaYqAdfbrR6GHi/G09F3pcA@@@IHcg7ZB99PvfH7ERmER9igRd6qdA8OPJETr67KBPHLrjy30GzZx3nBjwPz3UxrXajfveBSLpPEpXHWzI8T1CJzR1RJ8wP0Zp@ocffgDrE91d@C/8D@47n/PhzoXQRTR64o3ETryfnSyZRMOEjGXdrkDATaP7BrqPctyJJxT4rJxl8fFf/8//@qv/@qfk71fk9x@RJEma0e/DTx2iMVrBMRYR/ifhVX8nzOFwT1y58PueYMolsJh9gIOtOZ3hoLPxPX7d49NH@CP/cGxu8fkjibGjCcjr46MbuZ4W1NEFf7Q6Yln2aEn@HnGYZReHjsedMM2ygXvlA34hP/Lx8wdgmeAhx@npZzIPQo5ozKGq5AYNAWsYqUcwci4E1ENo4cMHdbRocvgPNXv4r27iv/YY/9V5/Jca47/SqrQ6SBHQ/8tEwvNzD7//cR2ijn44/yHx9zhI/YAOmNMcXVw8PD97fHf@7888Z2f4h/9BH6yDZ@SwQkDEg8fnOb87P/dfXCwufA8Xd9TRF@DJM3UUcIDw3p9QR4nFeZ1Qepe5sGl@sqfpJQif@x7uaiUwxZvewLnvKJBLpr2BRit1xMJdeHuLE4P4tp5NZqotgK6VsslG9rLQzrZqEG88PF58/uzxQ6t8Bu5cPAAti194LjwJ0zTR7eOJH717PB4IWbfUUeZi0aJ950BuyY6pk4J893B37/ZfPPxIHd0d3bk@BT4FGJmZMeyYHZfV6va/Wl0sQtVI9TOCdGnBjFSdGTJDtg@yihihxSyZ5YKZqFW2D0EB/pgJBCVGXDADRmEUlt3D9/b/pKqWqyqgUiGbuWBMjJUR4TqoVsuATISCR/AnMQyzAEIXzAz@GZn0G/b7RwbX0c3c31N3yPGDAArFzzr9jNMfcTqlh3BEe/ryHIg83RFzIxx/uBMWkvngQF7n4/1dPB53Ppwd0cb9PW3pWEcg5DjDIM/Pj4@ZZDP5@Ejj1ZfF@bHns8f3GY7Ehefcvnw66l@cfbo/9WEJt6Tc/3hEn3@6vwj6cDjiAb4HIO6c/tm9ZoMSrh/vKadr3ul08K8zn82tEAlYcfedTSo@dWiIskI4Cg4MSh/Kvx9YvBY2l@su/PDl2e12f7h3njktRrlcSAAb3eVg7xcBEQUcbmK8x2HkY4PYvoqE3RcXkTDcR2Jun4shyVaWe4emafcOP1kM8BPHpkQiqevckgCFYPC9d3D6473jLvCQSMTDJDrsi0eQqvviQbfD7f6ePT@3ywi4IdrhXDhU3Ym@PO/@ub48n7vI4cZ/bjeOtM8Xbhcku8Nwt/jiWpy7zl04DqJwri/PFzhI4L5A6M7lfnA/P1txcHa5zy2cF27gG17x@G/4rxrI0JDz6PkIG00KCoXdrt5ScIcirpgnbv8lPkIFXI6gMwj1cjg5593d55PgSTR09@nh5OHEdX7iP7m/eNhT4G7nEYKushbtBHuE@UYd@c/qDjbgcGJRP8OPLlRZ8MvqAAXjZ/vC4Hx0nbw8Ymzcc@L5fHcSj1tln5z8@BF6JaCDwhxwHIH8Ihc6vzjfCNUG48J9AbBfkM1kCD9/ATmzEsEGc9kPJ@7vF4zV29FZL3H85Yh7PiP40bPDebYnrwS/y3lGnl45vjiOOf2OfXA8O46/9J6xsXrCuolNFA6dnZ2ErHA0BmH2xG0tyIYZuFuHIUUwOJ4ohrMjLE5O4LkbapXoCQNJAQN1j0mecDhMB@C8@EUkG1hQZ/gpj/VIyeFzWB0IxeIE3xEyjDgF86EetPwcRRkYtWX80oYqih@teJjYoZ4ggG0tyDJensTzHjD/5f4c5tofqSPQY2BiGQIckxonTAVhPp3Ohc2RloxTboRcI5i34@On3/zhT7/5H3/67Z/89Ns//Om3v/rdr3/1h/D7a/j9iXX9k38bD@Pz7379v/yvP/3lbyHyP8LvP8Dv3//u1//iD6wfuf9P8Pu/d@L@k/3bgbN@FOD6x7/79Z/@1e9@/U/@HH7/yv79@cvfT3/276z//8f@w8Hf/vRn/wmf7Js//BPqb//mN/j/T//mb//Db/D///av//Zv/vnf/uN/QwJ/YQX@33/1b60zFP6rP/7pX/wjqNOf4fA/hDD8I4/POjw2wB/hyB@PGTA30f2Pu5A/0iyMQIjeifwj9OM9dhtlt5CA/1/@SDMwSDIW5AbnLuQf/@7X/@yvIPZHGF9Z1ob8R@vstgztQe7RCQX9EUD@5Q7AH/30mz/46a/@h59@8xc//eYfU2A0w/9H9JEKIHzFJxxJAiS0OKHCQZDTdZjdhoMhEg7D@ZDlgZ/lfPq8F2XhPjkETAA/kfSPBw0ZXMbJmrZDhX1c5z@I4RP6DMkwZpFha4HP@AZicJioPHJZRy1sQHJvwdj3OzmtGOse7WTfj8eROxnXl0PRVgIpcg2EbGQLu1C0RW9Xg1pTZgEvXkVQyK4eRUVRqwaneuEy39y5NrPJdJ6KoFS1knlxCdtAYVTK5pqb26iVus4a3qDoZkull7f2patOEc9h5UQ2hViQbZv85@csS100sk2IaFYRG2D81MUNWvhRrXZNYX34EYWjXq/f74cTvnrJQa7@4@/XIOzblvCR4XCopRVVxo8a4qzl@SHhfBDShTh@1g3KdK4QV4Me3h1kqr0dCRcchYO6NBiayJyrGwDDMMCG2lhXa8tqY2F1UI/j8O/nHlCCsHuY70eYVhkk7lWK/BqcysOYMsGv6WPnLxNPvSURMZQfj0CBQDwWjsWDgZg3Fo@FwmwkHPayAS8bjUXjjBcm3TE2EgvHWW8sFA@GQqG4FxoyHI9SR4LSl0SahikT63AgEpAUHr9/eo5f5FX9wwvqqC@IkiJ8QAtX3/3hqL@OQNMYcgRj9wxy0LSDjVD4EeXJIgG2N354G2RBezkoB4d4dJTLpZlczuFI4RtQwEyacTj6@CYcY5hoyuEQSEo6FmQCkGmI77IRBnvzOyR8k07mchjDCN8EYhiHwzG2UqwbeX0TBTAF3wSDGAFyOJ426BhArloUxUgu07phmFTa4Zha5MXgD@CS1l2IEJvFNzgBZ8pZKWlIczgu15lgXHE46hacXVR@Xd9k0uEoWDfJJEZRJJUPW5W6wjdJckAmHe5AfB2OAQQGOlgMDkcPgliIHQ4eQvySg7gJhLD3q2JyDsfSqgeuicOxINAcP3Y4HtfxUA7Qk89zQ7MvDKxjqVtXHpIKkCQtptlc7/KyNxj09GUye1knScVinhstp3pv0LMz9h7hUHEuSBpPli8PASc9PnLy4aQrSFJeJD0uHwVC4SP3BJTZxwAXNHks4qQiJB1azrARwjEB4B4@UhO4prielbQ@SBK5Lno9xxlILYX7D1q63F/IxNKFDGklgNpxMd4pTHfCn6YxRyTqOD2Bq@OTIwjBhQsxTjBgHc57h8N9F3/45IiGHafOT598zu/YT8gRjTtOHdGoA7nPHAHofGGHI4ICUYfjFmw@YeBzok@OM10wp7qCAmfPmIJVgjkjlKAnF75yXnzuub/YYL2zZ7z4DWQ@uVaeBOtFK/cnTDHM22Cm6z4ldTh7pulzrBpYvA5CUxc4T8JaLge4mGOTYimPTe9HPh/obwQ/n4/C6VrC4oPLEXchMEpFCc73DmKzW2uYLqczGnA63c4zQPIROXb0ufuM0IosnrrWjHEAK4AxcZhi2rV3xX0wAUK@OFD@iiR9fGqYnI4XtUmJp8gRiTtwNN6OML4u7LPXx3pPT3rh84v/jrIM8ghLHT1TffxOaiiOzuJneH0IZornF3aeK7SMDjz5HZLPqGMnJtoZ3Js3H5HzMTbijnxBNaQeHR8fU0fnzQtH0FH1P25WAy5osqp0f3EWSqTxRB9sPP/94/nHn7/IhjP7Lz6vl8Yu8KLgqyMUonQBu1/18Y6G1kQ@FsZ8HSDjCNCcef4uB5RMJQApdYbneo4jDToXL6MlXpRE91ZFz395RGb6qPZl7Q4zVcgTu9Myfj7j4k4bZPeAuwfk/mVFkr/Egr4LssCNJRRBSz834t9Hv499X25VW9XcZ@Y0dhq7v7eb08s6WSdpKmtJ7DOMVFI9Sx0ZP7rVMPtLpXh2dKo5gyEnGL73iSOr8mzUfXQRiPoNbnn0YPuSukJRLLBwT2Z/ARYdiZ39Y753M5uQxUIoKvYP@oOBFPgH5R9@PKZppxMM8eOLL99wPN@dnz@f4@PZDuDT8/Pz@at/ctkeb8Bs0z1/p5Un/@PRQ@SXvnPr/xxO6arFHUck7HBj92Dj@8fvH48QTD@RIxDGPdlDI2uCuTsddi1OlO9PFPgTTgzyJwjkVjk5v4AoAyLsewFDCO4TmqavA2CdxOORWOSI@j1Nv/doHVI3z5pEQdCN6eTQw6akLpU5/CBO2TxwgkB5uhJ0uK63SFybMQjbMfhpKjZkduNs22Yniuwsuh@3NGjs0IdjKQqHJLJjLRKxenThBRaTOGahE7yvK/ZbdlNfqA@Aa8qbxBcQTmcU9QE7peFb1xrOi74zTDd22GHc1IcPtp43TL9hPmLkOJMd6WPPqGcKs4fr9w2EnwMS/xvL2ZnDLl6qZr36JS@RlckgA5llkRE/ZVzuDsEnSLSogNqcIFIioRxXzir@gwXWm4qYlFyhlIU8KIFE8jzZzu3Qe3gHL1K9j6LbLhwxEIWxYHDCKQKOAQEdRLoIbvcEe1TzLgLpQSxOF8lzaYACC9VLKPEi0c54h28fIDtGL/KyagBiq3SXVQN08mgXa9dhPXziSgALce3I2ETGWH3Ae@3Ww1ui3D240Ze136YLp6JzFNg6ltq4oDGszXdJRn7StwSHbI1ms5lgYx@80LRnlv@fawNnx2wZ9UydmN7JmdVU2hl15eLdX/Bzy7NfTr77jv9eu5s8nLknCRNfPZ4JDJVjl2SBnJiJSQLEQ7uTHs7MO49HekhM3FcufA@jMBgVz5RoMdtw23WDmisJoAX7Nhhu7@pO8f1SefDm7hQPkDz1ntwmVl4uwXgX8JPA1JC9TwnWrgeUaSZWHuWMO4cffoS651sJZoOHO9uLwlnGLjmxuuMeEsAPGTJ6PDmoDNBp3Mkez4MbCpch8XXGM/m77ziPfLE4k30@N4b6Pvgpd2dC4MGTwPenLu588Wl1N4X8py64JqAY2Q3EQz6b188b2oG@M@Cx1aZb0i0aF5i8BZA3SSRObj@d3J4kPn5c3S18kwevxf5TZisNmPgFJv5sx3fVdXLrRi9YQhY9XY5fSKe/8J8YyOGVPB5gslfbyWlReHILKRqM3TbVz1hfkj1B14/nsYTZ/pbWFmpksyWyqk62LjXIds1mH3ueQ96kwUuSDW69MqBJMCvm8CajXqSoio8jEDjN3qMYJ94vPn2i1kXbzoBQMlYuPQFxeHZNtqjU8Qos2e/aesvma/r1kBpe69zNnLJRuM0imL8GIzvdlagm0uEMnb/DIFgNfGGezyyNZbmAgrIh2gNgiPbAcD6sRTCTbD1hQybsRGitdQNBLqwnROstI7xXl4H1E6i3bc8HFWKRAZ35ABmSd5QgugnkSYIQks5JeRCArkJ9gEpgGnAdpAd0AYoMffcdsm/PEzAnj@KxAINhuJGHxUCvKIXCv4FSwIGpHIGMYn1ICgHaPuAU7Li8V1Do71eQ/d6BCzJ4Rl7r9QM/ef3ANVUM660bzDe3RQZuiw8fRp5EyCYI/slUAfJD2vPvj@zh/hSlq@Vaq5mtl5MNOMNcJ7bdBvl0s2Huq20yNbz9ZU9SiJsuz9VZoVvkwYQBw9XEuynh7bD7qNgqoUCgkvHivQ@A9UfW2hcMqKcbTIJB9pUz/Ko@oOfSWKL399HHWxcTj2Cya79vvY8xJocMzvL2XaDtq0AGXtmCwdx@YXtvJ/WJYBj27p@@9YbqZNN48lbUBL/cA73Q3i2UOFut/UWIdxJ@@OAlPm@6NJDILtlDC8FefrKxo2llJ/2Dwrt89jmTwxJNxWMMc4oYLw6w60BgHQiuA6F1ILwORNaB6DoQWwfidoBdY2YtzDAxDQYj22B0G4xtg/FNMMRsg1sMocA2GNwGQ9tgeBvclhbalBaJEbzoaM1N0nUFHaexodg6Db/Lp5gkMgxo2JeRISA08AoSsodeRUJ5sf3IaJyxCyrQVQwUCES296B91rAJl0WV16LDa5Vs3dmRMFZR1kSNCGxW10ErZRd4W2MQOvcpwu82UBSoXcTLAgfGgGCClZLIgfwL7lPrnT99ebp9vwFjSLCbe8iOt/2EPCzZodsSnwPJgUPJFrbAQWzWS5Now5idl0NsIi0qT/dGWgtjaC9uF@tHrGAxR9@ACFgQuA323yZZl9nUpweLDL5f5B7Cg0W@IsrCGz6UC/PGRZAn1lnJ@E@wJdblWXaKQFobzAD7cwxEBl40KH75M/GFPXX87td//r@j3/36T3@LfvrL3/5///5/xuF/h0//B9gsKLAB@JM/xad/iU//HJ/@Ep/@bCcTgQ@eOn7689/A7f/0b9BPf/inVtI/@yuHN7RBBCk4apvzV/8Qn/4RPv1fDm94A/irP7YAcRaH95naM61cAPUn/xEhKA1j2SD7879GyOEBA8NlS96d1ccfdl4VsxBs2HBHQg8v060zP9Qx2xm3xwF47Tt2e@fBDeDeQa5z@PsC274H5ozlooy1NM/xQ/w6kB2lGtj@4bEJoxr@AcjbvA9Gj7224YTa//foFDk9GAaiyTuvCUuH2/W36@3YpmJYj4MG6vCWvTYqHHZvKIHpLQXyTWYCS8OPpy1kRspaMmLzt4K/X7IeQBxryZJMF@um7LLWuWHSg@xt4OF/O9XFQouHIeudUfI5Bsp@s4XdKXBP3bxoNijlZQxMGbdvke1mJRHCRIMmgWwbfmPG4hvCBe9LdNuWs7tNtpp70WHw0QMTc7yrkTYFJZDD8RVYzGkb3o0truA@vEWvDXDHnAYf9t5JOwTsuLm5cVA7cQyWIb3vIhh2KmWpjE0Su58U2EkK7CQBzRZOomvCgcALGsjAgfXi/vuXVrYdFbWfbStcuOes2wGTAXNBa03TK8pTY5h4jZpo5H1l9xr5Dkr2IWH3k3uF6JwL5HC/ygA49/MkXrblYdTMK5jXDXU4J@b2Xsxea72NaS/PTqcg3KNecmnTcmz8UMvtF/gOavbB840FBZi/Z0G@bywoEv56QS@bFefdQ/82f7@udtZqYqPht8isjn@0N0DhofHPQfS26ghTrJOgyw1TnqQ95enNVeQ6sN8/xNPrzY72NvnXd7ZAwpOYimoK1vLAZ02FKYeKreCdjwQd@tCX/U2egaLqgrH7rqlkvbejOPHbzrw6UGBU8@JNlyT7Cxb4Wbu1r8X@uLIZ2WwrNG19dwijthiFLc/HR0mRzMdHMD5l0b1lIL718/hlCieFP1gEoZ38ro1pW9VcKt48znR/HSexd61sTYkfu6qaneiEQpIIJnS8IMPkCw05fow/vUVYgqtI3vzEFmnPdLkxE4fqRB0Iiopf9Ma5X6AvbHFjgjhNI7R4EedF/A5F9iTaxXs5t5316mdnRVcBF@fe5A/sI9hjhhfpL3mMOasfKO7xzeKsbOvyGj@f3sYuvY336RUl3TBf0kwi8WoPvv68ooOuLQYA3JIR/DoZXntvh1fk7JGyicbf0bAyfDOJfcHgYfjDlCYBNGmD@0WQD@/mzoC7DeHtt/j/fgOus2e/tfmIMdtYgr6ZZLHtR6ZoBtnZRuEFF4AX3Fj3vC5uI9qZbyzLnuiQGZ4XOYjiUvA7OdAxNU1QjM2z5jXir8g8dgJ6JffEMyhhJR6gSZ950TjwdhNlHvuCzC2FvsuG9O7gXde4LnB9oq@@reJY0RGlp1ofT3ExXnbPFCPvThKg0zdEhvPO3O63xcoCkTbSQx7GEQoLb/OPLNy9VM14ETRhPQNRddCgR2TTFLJVjbbUltb71rL1zTZbj1rjj9WSFfwa@lcZAnywvsjFerfFut9Tn3XXpkrfMCJsYP37VcavVK4x4pcaX7fhz2PR12tKVhk2mRLrVt6zTt5qcem9Ft@RirVMWlbJt4nk14Tum2VuR9QsZFsVlv55Q8grzGlOlnnetYvRinm3xVTllU7AcbjFVOWNUeXxgELd5CSazsSb3ycs@8JNSRAswHUG1zZcMUKYgz5aArWuG7Zr10teJGXCaTtWix1zx2NbdIeL7t3niDtQ1DqMF3KfN2Xyb5bJvyqT3ytz0wP2i9wBovi9Iu1WwM3zXhPIgmi@oZ1xEp65w@U9tQ2HonI6fvb6xSk5TyUvcs6cp6CQnYLzNOsCpezsO08zJGA4TxskMHaeXkFg27ecPzpP190CA@hwSwKfcbytwvE97zxNu9zPFPlS57pcv/N006YA88m6JRx5tpZXe/ZTf3WzqioIXsuo9CIsMQZcVFytuwcv@THwT0Dtncgg8WMCBU4IMJ6A7A0aOyOGVQ4MG37yKUDXoeHjdL00Za9vbNdQIN2T2FlUwVIyJfrIeeTcV0YWYTiVLD7CFQjEevP0MEWIfTUz@xo5dukgoaSR98sn3PMTe6DvIul3ALy7iCNv86/bax@F1YDfRifO/Badr8hZF0cows4A7gNkYab@4HynUritX@xqZbX@bgu9XiPAjehbg1itRNDu6HSw4bBtSgrTVG1fSEgqfton7ebBh90psfS@yEa0gt0z30gm0XbNsGLY7fzu96qzkw@TtqeCcOId82D1ss24QHQxTtrquh1L1ep8QMKOzumTDSkELLYZO0jgLHXjJWPFW8PQOq9VJNFc@2oSMvvx63JTzrRK3z6XwS/R/bzp6zonmOBAI0awk3NTiqVf1Z9hv6uW/b42qNdMeFHAIcP68FD62rx@d5R9Qbm8LfZ1A@JEL8q4DxpHmxK2LIfZwY5l/p6svTLx8TeRLCPfKnSD/YW1v2bbZk7wFb69nFtYuLCVoM/2I8d4YXYceJtRry0SeeZfGy1@XJKNx6r4htJt1d6n1ar4oSbGKXiMhsvPbmB9v4F3Gw/jIxXQX7Dc6uX425LkOcWmb@M19Z0nF9ZTBxV7iW32aNuJBHVP/Nc2LloQUX2sZ6qVUhcG3Wg06n79KAL3Wsi7Hcepdx8TbKYtAS/ekId88Rr7TgxV3fx4rzheu5SRCDAGOPLcxhI/u4@7bV22o89f9F3IZ8HucNTGNd52A25PK2FTh8NDtmTz1dqP23XC2UjW5i3w20tma/ipEZYO/EDn8ZEMX4@P2Dnn8dEexXDTbB4j/f7I/iRXYOez1Uf73kzE4jJe7XqBFwCmE@ujyfYCnL2fheWHcoQ/UG6uc29yTRVTWjs74PUh/Ihq4xnhCrJu67vm6xjr8@Mgqa5ACE9hA2H89rGVC0PjhU/iWmmX89EydPBmrYamKvb3ycfWN@zJ1rHGeumVkD1V5hxxA7FKIS9N71BkOWStn4uRTw6THdCt7ztzirWEvOaNFwkDP3niE4jDlGMsadZ@bRvXD8NNMhGCiY8W8LgnCxP82V@Q3QOryWUJWmWYkwYDECTa3mTecnBp4i8B@1TRl17vQ3KE2uTjzfY@l7ZPGNlj1l4HBna69jaSMVAgAtZU3Auc3f6AsdhNBuHNYhjipEWg4BeFS9QKxrw7eT@6lu79K7s@3BjfR9cjblnrbUtJxxvKzzhlh8/2S5g7S9P2Q0uiB3aeXK73RKLsPawS5DmlH/uoaS7HkWO9UxQOWm4TnMyvt1hx4c19TqkPClE82AMM8ZZvDRi4CjbayOM198YlVUG/QMEA@UImlEesVFIs4LCe7O1hhzTIiom1vPtsBeP4Rd/xC/wwkfpwhHWhJWs4/1qUcZjseLmVZfTRRmc9UMFd2eoC65vwzk0QphofDhT80eXwABaPw@3YwwTw9tOPD5bmfZ0VlKL793SzH@nk1GQy2Zywev0yOUgOk/Uu3KeYkqczCmVpOpuX@8lMobe8VKPNmRhgmt3rVC/oqUX7C03KT9J5LUtJoe7EcxtcxPOhVTgdTCd55ka8LImhaPpGvDGEpCzE6dlofN0X6lqP1Q3pqlKu1Fd0rnXdHlyPxNtOZxRVGpRWv00NrhfCdayjzNqteMG4FtrpijmujMwpu6xGO5HWXDFS7WZqWFwW5uNFIaJ2pXD6Woi2RS0/55dhjc@3qNtZcxhp5JfjODvpL5Npo9@Nejx0N50axPJ8/1YsNtJX/YEe7oXHjTgXnE2KorYcXuWVp9Io3ZjxHm2UK0RmlFIrzOZCqDPuyXnltt5u9zKp2nzMGrdafxTqlKdmL6ZHgsFpUhiOQuHC1NRjpVTyKmpmkoV2Tr5pm7fLdqxGmXmzGW0V@bjsmVVNPjjNtGiDaS@K0lVjHskHmmpeKcqFUW18Ob2sydp0nAlJ1eYkpA9ucj01EMhfN2b5bonSQ8VON1YfBWIZfsHTV2FVnQSb8UpJLy@mqaeq0EnzjZTQizCp8E2WHZWrS746K9XrnZrWaU2ixhUr3@aYEVW94RvJ1DhXmsTYZmVZiF0WGtN0urCY9QLiQE1O@51g@SYyL1WEQueaDua5qVn2SOmqTI@KRWPZbl0VbirGLXTrclEKictFqp3SxadM2ijXS3RFHw8boZHS19pRKa3yxVohZBbGyfy8cxsvpMaCWOuN1XGzI3emppQZ0TlqmR5ft3rCPCet5lw2VGpf06NsnTejyUGwQY9EsTeWq8ZqcFlaDRrT3qAfr14yGeHpqp9qh@tZjS3njFBFWVLdZkqUVvVrkR3X4vnCbS@blMpKOF0TtNplfrYIBLqSWJuHV@ziZpQLSQs@xJSqqZuy57oYqHtKnlSqpgarAyqQyV12BuErj5oTVnRJ5J6iaY8@nYYWmSn@0HOppcj6JCwzsVzTM4waeideLs97RuGmnu7w8ip2Wx6PI7d16mZWMFQ9ECvmknG6Nmb0S25UKdxGJSUXmqcu5Wy80Fm1Yma2NJVj@dIgU6zrmeaEv4lnB43lcjyIFYVaaZykhFimXh/1Bu3eotswakumHOJHPU/2Mlt5GkA/bjdygWIrFRlM68H2VUaZ1Zo5z0q96ZS0dGXMZmuxaaQZDU6o2aIYSzZMRdIyl@V45HoqlbLJzKCVZlVBuHnir9gx12gumZgR1a9zN9ea4TGbPTXUG6aCy@tyl27fGkY4L1G3i06kkBzr/FV/YRaNaFMJqNVrhr0WKy05POtIT92aOkpO6KvWzYruzVe5Rc3kzcZYDfej4fHlwnjSV1f6FRXrjji5VUmrpREfuepKqygdZpVmNy2W@W4xwCRbg3xZyOVng1VLmARG@adpnud4o5bs9i7lyGyhecRgbFaimpXOzSD69MT0hEo3LiXHrXqtYAaaHD3tNkrhp1LXMHJ8qyClQpIyzaS6l@NJ@nbJNY3FatqM9GRxWdMDTJZaVLrlNj9SB0bOuOVHq5vcrVKeBiI31ZEYNftjdiKxpbbIRCta3ZPx1OTL3mAZaU@FGQ@WoXZd0NhUcjSqUlV2Ep2llnHDVC6Nq0ovXUxKyWQpFrjWAtH8OH2ZX/Sldqtdyfc5NXTbSwcj1d6ACfRTleygFpoMorVKNFRKU83e8rrO9jMxiR1ycnpUXIa0eCmQitDteT1/PWoOlYqcTnYWYirIN9V5tMOJSktYRaJ0mfGMhvGikmRCtQjVMjNmq5SbBz3KVaEcqC2X/E2PmwY58alrePjuariqtgVOlYelpzrbbE9LaWk0akdSfJOpphrMdGXMOa1Uo@KZmsJmSotZbj5sdBhDy@S1WG9R6adrNaGn9YOa2KsmFyIz63Rur69bVWVycz3J16O96qrPjcJtU6xHqguTegKTpz0rtXK9RUY0xFF99qRcLqY3bTrUupyUWv2ZZxS/7c6C0k2VKVVSbZGbFq4HUbNVWWjloizK9CRQHdDUvFVbrUwhqWYr83J3IbZXq6SUMp7YxRXNlS4LmRvTE8/mkplqs8HpcrV6Wcokucm8PC/dRD3CqlHuh6Xx0y1VUxQ5oN825GiKCRqBVjizSvOjS2Z6mZo0i804q7GtfLtcvmKHMj/ho91qJtIp851ksni1LIpcu1bTaletJlX1KDe3t0262pRLcbFUqDfVcGGmlzudKDdXk9ccUwhNevPSIjUvT6edSbzo6ZoCF1RXgsDW53KJFvIgOzFKmM5q6UrNWAaeVqOnwSyj3rTjSe0ykkwvxf5MmK2YZGbmoY3cYt6PSFos0OwuLsUuXx4MruqpYVCbac1IOkwV42JZaffSw3J8KVzlS@3c1BQa/V5I8hiMNmpeJ1tGi19Kl3xkOGsZXRk6n6iFm6l03JBvM7ErXfIwMT5F8Z0yV6NLw/BNpdhX5@lFub3MwJQjxoo1JqwulfY0NlbyV0bqqvN0FYsNWr38GAqeDm@HvNTypPo94VqUK9TtzVV7nK1N2/To@qYcrbXyntgqqF8@8erwkosvm6sqwwhifDArTBdBrcTHLmNXVV4uLir1ligMIo3AtXyprKiMEh0ySZGdz@YK7VmGU7HsQEy1KoqeafH5qKDWOJpedG7NaucmdhW4ZK6ZxmTOBIzynGbEriItu5VuN9CnUjPjSus02FnWkzeT3caozl/KdKVTL6zUZSkbMFrJSlq8ms6XWmkp6cFbvnSZlmu8xIJZEo4MmnprvErNelRHXJTSqVj0NpAHCTIMOT7vhjiBN7TBYkSXytO8vBhNx23dM1nQdc9tdxGOD9tDg@ZLpWalMM/qYbVojBQqEuED@Y6uRY3602RZSJuZYbslh9Lx9qBXzXfpclO8il@nG7dRIVyjC09CvNOIMHwp3OFptq5OZiaMSPxgTJWWTF/nZUHnotPqUzg7nXr6y9nU9Gi30curWGcwTrMznvMEkz31iVu0izIjVaLCwKh25rObXAcsRKU9aylU7ralBa@kvNjIt6vlMVtL1lcmnYp3@JvQoKuzoiLO6kEzXCwIgygvZrK341EmX3gqMF3xiZmzsn59HczlWSoqelKm2pfp9rV2rawCnJDsVmPleX@VngwropAvBDJ6tx7pN644OQvDqPRUYrR27rJ02@/JQ1pUlWqjzjDUbSSQ7dzUn9hZ/7q2aqqLvD4oJmty8EYsKGrtps1mrnW6Ek3lrtOj@m16GYvUdLknNAexpjLxXAZVnksqpQgVFWZCqt2hW4IUZKOLVY8bCzR72xmPY3l6FTFWdFIx5qPYYBXvXU7Yzm1FvWwux/TlZHFbS92wU8HDsjVeo67NVS18ednxXC0vW4WB3CqIPM1NliMjn5oKxXnvOpL0xDSm6cn228NFqTbQOlk62uvF2EYw2AmZT/3a0riuUO1MKR@MZpbmQsyOp5VFLK8lI43lonUdCo1vR4tqrBGphxfsTB1nU1puEKbVGyOqLJr5QS4lZMWyaJRXPX5CRVbTSiEXy3rCAtetdW8ZMUs/NfqyORyIzaubYCNC8@F8tTa/vc0k6UlUHGUL8iWMiXOuvFg2Rt1x77pqBCVKrXY9hcgqsmrcXlf6Sq1TLA9780E0WtPz7VF8uupqdanu0VatQk@9zNQmcmZ1AwIXqcfDo5acbXWkm0ydqVJmpJOcgw3OpkrSckAXwsyVqDDFxeQyfjPpRMbdcTs9q3cX41GkEQ2rU2EVNTtP4anQinaLkwbN97rzoSdwSamN1fImex3SS5W5VjJrqnDFxAKl23Frkp22PJP0Va5npjuM1gt0SvOpJx0GqyBWbscDld7VKFUYX14b@etAnGrmpOU0NrqMXHpqMJhMR0Y11pYD8ozu0HJ7PhPGE4arZLi2vui1cqV@pR@I0ZpHis7Nq8hTsVu75UwtpNCUsYz055wnnwULIiN1ww1P29SYCcxFmJtZ8EoZBAOGctNo8GZajY5bwbgQyultRW0v1FE7IF1fRsdzXroaUSlh1Q/JrXqnX1ms5v34ONTnGrNWMnejdIJpRRsuDJ2NxK8Cbe6pNtGDVVOrlVp8SrmecJw49yzkVKasN2ZUf1BJ9ju5p6k4a4eqyVByedNnQtPb2YhVVjfZbmBU6yWH4rzeCa3q82Cqf8kq9YmkTfQAzTTbSnYcW7TywhVVXGWF5TB2naq1Q62rUXwclAfjRo1ZjquSyN/eGlO20B2Urtl@IdxOXcfHedFICtFWXCyO6EWlV72NpPtCiKE8w8KEDqRLfLCYvfGYRV4OP0krtmKu4qKyrLSkXmMwS2ql/qg1raTydIoNzC4X1UkwX6eDUy41iWWu9K4uU0I2nFy0quWIMbxNmu2QWgvMYtptTRrcBPq1IcdPmEgMdHC537tdtpL11LzUreQbRlIZrASPPr9SLgu5XEqh8mKn8mQ8cao4TYZa1VL3@uk6qQ@a4Z5pFNjFk0Avl0q1mOb5ZTdZMMaVdrGhFKLMpJ8qR6@H/ZLSUmtS8Iri49HxTZRWGnxxygihWjKUe2pf8k@FWaSujhWTb2ZvWbNSB2VXCLeqWnc@WaWHjLgIhrI3RnXQ126ht45WVGCar3f7dXGkLOb1otm@Ck4a7Lg9l8cRhdM8oWy8WuXYQRBPwsI3qjJR5auBedOozK50mh6uIlNBuxSuJKoU0AbJQj1SDHCXl91MvMVOnkpCIFYOTZPzQLVe9ihhQcsUBhOZSY/rI@FagilDJ1IbFZlGRWoNbqfpm/iyQa26PTGuFDtz9So9nmfGs1GztQjC9KrZLhlGo35j9guzQK8YlXvVYb@ZyaWv@TTHGdGqks5Wx9q03ZvM86EwNcoFb0blaFEaRMbRgrDsXk21eK24KqSH@ZCnqxRjZpcz5aeqPHqq9Eyz9xSV2o3rIt1JRXmFeVpGzZthhzaofGySvQwJ0VVhyEZbymQ2nfardUUtLGvXZWBzNBBsXvbopNa5rpntfl7gb/ItsPSLqlBo3BS1xuVNvj/tK5QcBPFN0/rVZcnI3WTGt@y8UF/2JNYzrl7Nq@FoWIz3PLPwpDKcZsLhTnRSrMxyGU2PLMqg9Qe1Za0k1Ctlip2Uu9mxpyiybEwvr9qzUD0p3ER65bk4D4UzyYUyjMVazOK6eMlfx3paYT5pFdnBNT2/jY@NCdfi6kleFatU6kkLLjMLM8uEs1eR/M21MIrM@9lpoJCcNzqFiBmviJ1O6Glen4@FSo4Vm4vZPFDLVa9NJRRetK9vx1fQCmGKHyyus1GhHBL6jLS6Tes5tae0uCRDF@nAvNW@9qgD5akieMa1QC6oRbLMosbBzPg2NS32I73WSO5cpvLxIdUP8VlP04gUbiNPN09lSb8ZeaITUDkxsT67LoNJ0jNbzdDiWox32VU7HetwvdyKzV7RyVA@P40XAoFiKV7qUkYjPAFpeZoHbooZOXBdazdDU0@mkln0h43bVj09L8duu@yk1mnMingyFqSZuVgd1VvLSm7RkoRIdlzPiinKU7ieG9W4JtYz7axO1/piLjQa5y9zl8L0ip8usoqHGRRay9nTdCLEimWZE3QlVzeHST7YjY2DC76gJZ@u2tQyz2WLbDrWjuljiS@OKi1jZMw6miglQ0/hhcesj2rSVThTb94oo9awUtH5dDkQNYTMuDGJ3LZGi95MyPaLlGjGZ7y8uKxETCW1zEk3rfJ1sd9glnwtVqzk9AXTo3NPDWZm0q1Yo9Yc9Cq6VBrBwOnptlQ1JoNKMYfqNcVpwwIzbyev@rGBkb5kYqXiotqSKh7mOlsfZQLGTPfQw0k1kFmp2WJQnEcH9eurCaOnZ/2h56oWpW9HKXVeocJmP9jhjHG8LrLdbpvWsvWVYZRjrZ7n6lqmhXrgNprKr9hmL6j1p8NurDu5nD11u@WnXruRh@a88QiRRvmJGlxf5Y2oGOfZfiuVLiXVmcYU9UldDE1KarcV6Iqe7iJTmD8FrpjcqNBjK5XhapXii3pHiWUmvXKaW45asTYVzFaZ/m1Q0IqtzFM3N5yO@HRpwQdv1LzhuQlVFtNLPRaNsKH4jDOC7cmk7YklZckTDQ6Xw0AqO4tk6L5e71DZqifdUVXoBfXbCFehjVC/IptGK9psZOP1dC6dL11lb8RSvFHgbm483etCOptsRopXw3HoqssaKTpVHo4aAWpUSo/7tGnGplJDyhnZSz2zGN6OryfT3jw6KxndlXLFTaXBhBU5bdwpKdFI8rr9FK4ywWyZzt6uZCUQDS/iVJ8X@0Varo9vOjEpm6e78hAm0BmQ//FNearzom4M4x2oeXmlRNOt6qCt5@VhDSiUe1ONFydxaTwUgrdUnW7EctGOfCXy1W59Eu32pJtmMRgVpwuYv3YzqysxQ0Ort7qN4ZS5iWTBdA2Fngqd4eR6Vmkb9XCm3SzVQlT7qZ4R2UK2VGrfmn22UmUGuZnZisbyWZafpMaV7DLVSxXmOb7VyXtGnkCzz89y7aScbfc5Y7G8ZeKMnhRHVGQUKafEDGvOw21RD6WLw2qQkwvqolqMaZN6rRhIFbPXojrWmdR1cn1E2sv4RAovB2IyedkudNMDKnmdzowCbdHg64pnXiBgqZzM/f5nbxUi6LpCwKiZKvUR@XS9vc3F2TsbT5CdJ/Dr7Xv7TmBnn92NBET7/WqgBcrxOlr4DeFTqxDybNOPP6mAHy2evXy26GPX2wmQC97HA52QzyiIew9CHTrOvCHjo6S8RwB54kmeoODnYOT15F8Yp/ADGrxrlMAm8kadi/DG/VXaCEfwPh94h07m4WznkaeL3aUGEwhNxiki8NPr@AXeVeE7yEgeAWerOfehx/rM2V5@IM7QFLLTiMPnd5Cs9q4YGNM@Cqs1cfxmbwaKbMiyfrD2zkeiOJqNMZE42d8DKV7TO7mLP3hP@IQDCabEKRNjqs/744E6nIlIRtqot@CXqyeEwiEUhLIC31kbeLKRBE32w43COYbijL01lbV/JtkrCW/QRbZZxNt1OhHybba3@ojcJODFp1PH2SspRSeTtRRam3xM7iIPCSXBnE3ulIczxeNxm56E6WE9LhzxHes@06a2J@Kd@UDe2qdPUHn9aj3@hAL2/VVFVFMVfqg6DUS@G737zgnZiGzdgSacttufZgJvqvpujIjliZvsdcTXUfgpMfcip6Su4cylJuBHd5tdCWQV5BefPkwjobPX6biGHz7gLTTObN@J3Qp8obRpT5b4U@oD4Sd@BI5fpz89tTeF4RGW2w8fSJxkRVq0IMlw4eSzdSqvaks7s2SBPK7rcr6D8sKFn626vd8CuYbqgUw@4g9e6QBmgVjs3QNHF@TDCQKQTKjC4ZKgbJ6D4n183Gd4lxP0cZ223vEHw2O5IfvuPJpIIrv0wOUc2aBkDwzktnecILF3En7pjbgSXDitpA@j6UQjz5/9Fr02R/A3Oh81TtI3Of3GFH/g2oVYzAxpTTRuARx4xnvBzThT2G2adVtgxzfy8hWuD8ZXI59kAYJ5TteXWDfilw8wvr5K8nywPgLrQqZqOVZaZNh5STXcdlMD4/Bu1U7NeYqIH9wZRJFHomc7qSNIxXV9I3kCyRPOHL6RPMS4p8ZbyTok40/DvpEsQbL1TuThdBXSrSf9bwCY2MsTxPXRVB9NTpJd1oYeeCuQZ0thu5DHs2bsRgSQ1TBWe@znR/bWKOij1TqWsO2JF/RPIlYWABZpl9158P1WWkgq3szbZcnFTpkWT9AX9NXCbOdIYPEjKQnULi7ffbKHH@0QAP0PVCl6nb4u3GrtTUX35McPw84AtzYwK4h@/PE9ymxB3Jc/9mEtfVYLYT/cnRpa3Nrisb5cuW1XK9PKznQ4j711zK52W/tIbOux7pSBrQqx@ta2X4uS0ocyAPHH3Wjs8uRGn7Yxd8YDOt1ojy0frW7xdT4GXkkP9ogiPdKLetsg/@1c5bDcQ04ORuTeVlngfcK4s1fsNDbQvn3oC4DecPOFnPF7MmP30p9b2W@rzRHQRzo14c2ZpWh5MA0vbAIPkMdZ7bqrEyxkx85TKx5/kVPaRya9gczaT@8REJjnQAMe2dZqfD0mSorfeicV9DwTCHmJi7kF8rxl01pZfQuf/ht0Lsw4e8ie4o@U7askdIA1r8A39cb8unjZ5V5Uz9L0hyt3Z73U7PzkxDSi1/JEpO4TjJKniEGbjZvO0PPX9dDfjTNfts23Z@8Yrrd1xbrR15L4LSL4/P8Xd7VdbeTI@nP6Vwhzk9hJ29gkszuXt4kxBnwPYNY2STiEJcZuoDe228dtA76T/PbdeqoktdovwN77Yc@cCe2WVFUqlUqlaqlqCaOfFbJ0F9YvVYrjIIE1wzNLEgchXLwoJUfrr8wbc@xS5vZSCwxUbabLQbMANAVkKLutfG1z7SSqU0dfvBob48ZPrDDkBhWpIJN903PVObZz@7x4u29t6CjmiFuCm@ywMEeGsvDG2LZkBpt2hc4VhlmYDH7SnL6Nom7WGEzaYGAIJkIHVfIlnJU1q8S8TNATOm30qlsd5cOsu5v0ZkW/4nWFXsD41LIJIt7d8rTZxLRx7Jsw5tS1XI7ViFCZ2wc4rCjaR23MvkdtawK9WtjIaHzEJOPIlVrP80qcUg@ZSnuAg6EYDtlab2Xw3g4E6uzQRjuJb8lj8GuBl0FieOroln@6W5dwMyzAJraDbk5B5jYtNVtbGaCxAv/rn6sra5N4tHYdDtaCwT0Z1ddTb1UFA0m4tqEm45v87zgoXG4cfNbahM9l8yFEEhMaKWArDIKHLOqQ5YwoopmcJzHp@NBiyUMMYj433gvuu2T1S8SWYRQ/8r9T2iwUC5PhOOISjYhj16mf4c8knmqRbxHpHYMmZ4vhJHWyuF8gb6dyVjJfEgOphADLOQfEBVqyws18y2QwfiBUnye9uPTiQtDu3IEIyN5P2U7RcLEk//JiM/SItQZW4PIKPfYkysSQz44CBVsn8ZR/U/fxu4QHecNHXCH3ep/i8YFglPSiaAghx1FQtN8iBgjjXzVbe9VGo6CT18iJdZxyl3PMuCLIAes494I9xovT6ggXKIPyCp0FbMG3nQBn/cs8AlrNJkyFB7BTeIV4hNKDfIl/zXXD1s9JdWYJX3fSv2LwsqijegzJjgLvkmZZp1neNDOVHVa8epYb7U4HgSCOg35EFFeCXo@IFl68StiBR3DE4H9v8ccXwHlpiZfy/Fx5PlVekHIhKqlV6NyNkkobbqXM6p9JvV8qk1Tz53BtK@p07YSjSxWikUP35lN14wJt0sKk8o4dSpFKW7CVKsg7JX9fMPpSspJqYwXcll9IuZbvdT3ylspU3U9p/Pjr6QEKOAaDvrI4I6WFQdj7Q9yPtoQ1rEJYJWmO8Waxk0mpHSJaneRJTZAQ87Td2U6gvC8ZjcNzJrOz9SlT0C6pP7KzZEjWtbmJtWCOOFxinO@ZcY@8khAeLl5xQDBMCJoyM3fHNJ7qxlMHLGqtGLSeiRSanuDUtdkpvo1j3T/xj5nsaeJMvdXFha@E8kfpvNy0SDOIle5KZjGb0tpkPJoE8lJ36olVJME9nYW4WEmcRNiBdu6gKSzOQO6D3ESTQXfF6glXURhNMcd3W6I5nVQoGfFdNoQo/OX9c@2dd9Duk1XYCx5VGTZ1m8Pxe6nLNuMgHsc0BwLq4EjFk@GwF@q4buqBr3NIP0vrv@EyQgLRMRoKXg0XRKW@jyd9OYYaFVQdkB9wzzApiCe3yFwNTzCSMJNqvQkJ5LjglQdTjkzMYdDW5cpLoCaI4woF3KNtn0OEjJzMHvY8wEoreOZikXT1Rub3YEwmEHU84piHCLW64Xl/m4SdH5UDtV4s/rVU/FByWGZc1cXCh4@q5phIpmC9WCoWfyt99LxKNJzK1cZsJwdYH/MA6KsjLPSfSTaDeyRJ9sq0YnDFmEz/OBjdB92C5zWCLvuAryfMEYjyJA4kijLHecUbsq0Q757M3X7sK9p23UG94C/WZ4ld2@HAGr6HO0TDYNQPx3LTKLoPu2CguTd1E/V60QM7onFlSfiBRv1gTEx5l1NpkjguraaFbRcOF0vcQGIHDuB3Hd1zHGnNBrJTQ4Tf5wtAHoIoAoKLTBLBO5QQvk6vHfYhTgsIQJSlhAOGAOpad9IJnqTBYyL@TRqU7lg36kwQmbdtRmaNtF/Ec4WmezAKSfsmDOZR4WYO7TTArcNaUzXr@60v5UZV0fNpo/65tlfdU7vnqnVYVZX66Tln6FKH9SPSLk1VPtmjtyetRm33rFWnF5lyk1pmuMArn5yr6tfTRrXZVPWGqh2fHtUIGoFvlE9atWrTV7WTytEZLdYHviII6qTeUke141qLqrXqPmM1zbyknarvq@Nqo3JIP8u7taNa65wx7tdaJ0C2T9jK6rTcaNUqZ0flhjo9a5zWm1WFjnl7tWblqFw7ru4VCD/hVNXP1ZOWah6Wj45mOlr/clJtgPhUL3erRGV596jKmLife7VGtdJCh5KnCjGPCDzyVfO0Wqnhofq1St0pN859DbRZ/dsZVaJCtVc@Lh9Q57zsM1yhcamcNarHIJo40TzbbbZqrbNWVR3U63vM62a18blWqTY3lXdUbzLDzppVXyHjJqMmGMQtKqfn3bNmjflWO2nRmnF22qrVT3I0yF@IMURlmZruMYPrJ9JbYlK9cQ6o4AMPgK@@HFbpfQM8ZW6VwYUmca3ScqsRQmJiy@2mOqkeHNUOqieVKorrAPOl1qzmaMBqTVQgmMD7pUxIz7jXGCeiSx5JWD0juT4Pp6rtq/Le5xoo17VJApo1LS3Mtsqh5jnN5TVv4Se3Jz/gzX/l066Qp4PEV@p7VbL4JDNMJnl/RovO7@mPd6kyWmhsIf3UX0F5rbrqBteT26twcBNha26byRfsfnzrIz1SDvlOv3lPZHTWH8q5werq1dXn8hXtc5tXVzn/JS1TZDzXQkdhfapWTvexF7W7vM1P@ZZcRu280bHefQm87Ppa3ljnQ06trXUD3QyXFwHYuIl0UgIC1oVm5FuN7YFyUPIn5rSviDNmzDqLzOfNKKZ/Bj@TH7I2OC9IOcu5hbU17GGZDGQ@UZZ@QsJJQXRmED4HEN4wykIcBD9us0UXHbb82kGVM2247pi2gbfZ3DPNr4Pbmeb52fZMLO6asrFiwsGbMO0QzIh/aZYpPS6FEfcsK649/pMz1DAiMgpzgoovsurTJ9k30hzxRcVXmNu0ocQ5Hchx@WvtCzZzxfWPmzPvD@17mVu4dY7cNrTeXXC7S/5zeCkVaIKF2H4RS8KpfFJdW3PakFXG9qStjFj1d6j0EHZpTcVSfRfwso4I@RIu2G1Pi/EofHSpJzV80Cgf757t75PmBLUff//tr3/Z9HTE/dH4qy9/z4EHSS2Zu2RFP4RkpnGRM0sqZPfszyXLcbL7YPRQEekkzaDxyzaZtDZyptgIkl9D3EDobowMAwMk2cggScAoo3A/P1jxjLwunJlaALKprubQm377kS38NplKLAMdiZLZm/KoPeIfwLbT30xx2yEtQFrEgv5wPCXJpc0F673Mvgk4wHsbvlaMKoWMkeNh25xBEsZAZ3IUBtzB519atp1RJLsWA435ysPOLYmIlVkqTJIWTrlEKE6j2MxgeRnSm69a3ujxXCcHQhFSPZTHTWLjvm2ZN8l7xOesJ4aGfLmzTUP05o3FtKXgSM1posT/n04d484GJkUONKgZwObkkeWzLWEn9Ke3OfWnSCqiegPOppZY/Zskd1F3NJRNExJd/zYZZJTAShLK8KsHi8MzVc5NFcvOFJv@X/xg@P9BniyAv0UbToKecIv1cDiYBC/kJEMVXtHulZkSPpgTY84xtYSb7qvzBMwvd2DubMf0MbxH@bBELNCjMzUvziWlWHYBAyDk8Gu48xcBfHkS37Vp5/SJ5@4r@dI/GnT6w6xJyGWWijm4lz7bXL45IocfOfmEX1QOuiPkV/nEcR5ZZ2DDRVrseqpexxmB8b7EOgedXnvHTg87y1k0wYaSmeGJOBX11DKT/1GfMEpWma4p/UWm6PJkX/ZzCHIKpRS@@QJiFAiffXI7rNlGOHdA6MJ@I9ILe/mVXsWRrZJUIK/LqsXhOeL2De@ZsRTpWBoI2gGUgPO6q3M2XQfjBywXPYHOMUQSaCr7msOYAIn2RVozwijfXIG4zovsg6We3ZSQV0v92eDHAJmUA3FxmRqFVAYoNwRrQR23ORlU72X9ziTI34OtO2n8tQHHVenI90q45njnTliw038dJxwhi/MB1iWtQwmX2p0feJkxMho@5MNH@sO48rrnJqcR7Rk4Y90io//X0g0BZGXmDKzKfBtYJ9KGLGTbr435gieZu/bpHE/az7xNnSLi6A0OzGozCCTDbsIhzfnZxvSlwurg8OkGWU4PD4Xr9qTfHty0@2FvyqdO/xHdDdbiwSQeFoZTL5PJpL2BCASOEClE@zhQX8JBN3qI1S5NBziSmidnzdO048/xfFXE86XU/xAOtcuYvTnwN4iZFEc3YxqaYFNNdXLxUeLuYT@h9rSwW2uKFwhMNWIBIrx9axkfnJypg2AQjMgePOUzl@oo7AQDUh9kTPEpzPhONA2q7wN7U2NX@7Bd2LOzqYKQnTrWt@dpBBqaD9HK0lQkgkc6rSJ881MSdccnWJjvcNKvrnEq3UVDHQ0ITlMYm@LivJn0fA@5G7/UWofYjMvGnH0ztKwZXx98iWI69cVZS50ZtQfjKTHFm3XeENnP@W4KioMBEURvOTt5U9dHJvYu3H69mLqKzPBaC/AKQlM1CO@RLI7dcC8ZIz5nq91mCd82dXxFX9LXGdWRGj0vGT0fOUMLvvrtv1UrgOyq0167Qzss1Zyg@YcPZAfuRvEYVY/LShXXS6VSvvQBLtqzZrnAEwH/mwxinlc7Pq03WsRIHSLfCIZdM8F8Ttolp7GIHXmk7qLef4dCNvVJY65/Z@bBBDdxfDOb8sUis5Ghse@04e6lHsZpc5hdsnDJRyNOHIZoUCRCqelIWBH0ACn6WEkCkwPd59RlOvmYLC2WTo7mxw2@g7YeyVUP30O/c2N@RwogeOR31GrEO4OuDntPY9IP@pb6cGxW97ZU8GZznlmGiS@VhOOt/xZWEnEv58LpBjgjESN7QD@@74xIt7TvSeRwhMWExCKZYd2Us71pX4e9kOYA0dW5i7DgiLoyA8EuCDcjmscjbnPtYEFiWhZkK6DZ1Y36tqpQ5Xk2GJx@P4ynnUit3tI2GzuteBgEXc6UMBlKKgCUF2iW92jlkDBxG0mOAG@1yOcmR6RskJKFdN@kh9ixiPV3LWPumd6QVJnwgq07bOsFEPWoOeZJioxt2QU7bF/hO2@Oh71NAoG2OTBiSaA/AjH08VGKqKLxZoHgJxYXH@Goejzes3EA0ZCTEcXDdAFgyVfdIF1gwKPv@nGuggjptiVgJsSgIUbiZMlzygeW/oH@4twpgqZlpY/UuWnOMnM/RApN8Q1E6jbCv6hcMByTb4QBfyOcC1z4iJC8BG@2Zmm@JtWyCUScmusLYOYXwvywGGZew9QfK2uDew7YhlYsFtILiQYdkX4EI5LuH0RG9XJYuV4kH5hs72970TXyNpGmIGz4M/WTgXVf8w4sxWi3VIIIpvNNbZkuadL13SZju6gtmh/BjtoyHoudbwMZKF2wLXOJY5YpXrt4OvEj/tEzih8zqeRVsDpmsleBPHlLuhtgMxqkfpPZUMnMxEkct77GnG7STzUpzTTRxKWbXKearHtJpNKZ0UULqH78TffM2CV8KolHQG3bASp6/faj7G6KHICO3TRIGZmKiLd@qQUEFS86ysa0Q/VLLwnRnPpsLzjMTz6Cxye@M/@V4ZRXxXS@g0dzdI/VANdKlU85DPggqzuU02zgHzb8c84Qo/u1xU0GjqayHZYCL9XtEe5qZV0suQ21OmzLV0PUirGwuagvmAf4Sp@h/96prEaQd4mVSgirq1UhMZ5DL1/QVlaGxejBopeszPzLUXA0gp7obz4yJstANpuaV0ZzW5jyOKe7CRTeCzjG5En8z5jsOnmLFcVRDU0YfEhjqo284JG2Z/yNmUHw@mM91vqlxDS22kMTf5FgvjSrRroXS2vPLiWL6jiriuXCU5UNsy2fllZevtow6@BDgL6T6g7rjuAk1qwzS/DbWFjGVko45mCnUScUDZVmm6N0pa2/QAGnh9wQ58/0ynNCmesezi4jXmrlTAlJ1vmFNO3qtSSyE0A5L9UK/F824Dju6E7spfVKUk8P@zKJsLDMuD8lFrayGfenxEIqO8P@tFiYXIaWtdx@Vi5SIyEswKFEvWNgn5Krg0zBo1vrcaYWEzS9dGOZB73sAmodrap9nd6cqWRZpFOXpHHwn0cZmFUdaDQljsS8Czsal0lvaY3r/Ai6NiKz7r3dIu1k0kuCjOZsIgJ02mDgMbrMIWW2bUAaW5xges/cl7ObHNH@rWxYeA@KrF23d@nbvSmwZlUp5uYNShO9PyF@ayHx@fksCskWa2M@P7w9XaapxoGnaNRF7Yy34Iuv9wxV7x2q0r1zRijN4iWQ8i@ClH8BpDUHkp7YH2i95MfVEfLUBc@B@PZtHgb/@TttpDQM0rTdEE5s7IMf2tPnYK6QsbXKZ@racqrMNkjs5Odg/DELg/OC3tmvcfrlXRtet/8NRtFsVo6lnE3LygKKLFWr82T5IIu1Nu93dT1jKvHetvDj@i60O4HV50da4hjrxjhKfGc/Aq2mo@pbYMn8Ly3hn@8Ma3o@COEpNwxZy96/OR0KYIR4mOSqmG3gKLL0PlQXpBnxdOms8uPd6mz0YyQ8Xdos92xPPonDx3E6lahrorFSEme2cIlyMquV0W@LtmfP4l9diH8YDcnGuVlIANfvw48vTqkZlZ6YpjNb6xetZQvXs/l@uXbbTG6Sl0/yN3NdX6eu42I6TepB8KBX/6cg676YEfg/WPIXRkaWEPl6IZH40N7Wzi01mPSvg5H3kqkuLQr4I3uk5ZLreaurqtyhLbOOjA@vWIfT9wUaJcxgCEKsJkN8r4nlcCcmN3xkgQjwbN1u9DDg2oUMULCPth@0BzpUvl4wb0f4fmHr@kjfictdjCEcdIjRceC4P79LTupuoEtwIvkJtm4uHntINXBqKvwEkyZLbM3sNL2nlbdLDBxr1XCtjVlDxcgOPoa@E8tc20tkmOcWu8BeYj09ZRCREC9DqTe8M6CfltGN5cycDC0r7dC8gJWLzC3r5X6BuTV9qbn1H@Dk7IB6zrO2HvQCu/GsUpvd5Hv/Ag)

- MiLambda (145) [online](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php)

MiLambda is a 2D language with some operators being Greek letters. MiLambda code is on the second line:

```
EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
```

`E` is a Latin letter, not epsilon. The IP starts in upper left corner going right, then it is redirected with `v` and `>`. 
Each digit is printed individually because the code is shorter this way. `λ` terminates the program.

Each Greek letter takes 2 bytes in UTF-8 and the code uses 9 such letters. Prelude shows position in bytes, while editors usually count
characters, so there is discrepancy between the two concerning where parens are situated on the second line. For example, `(` after `bfz`
is at position 149 for Prelude, but 140 (141 1-based) for editor.

---

It is a shame that this site does not have general purpose text folding despite [overwhelming support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers)
(the feature request is broader than stated in its title). Such feature would be very useful in this thread.

Answer (score 4):

## 149. [CSL](http://esolangs.org/wiki/CSL), 6416 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4@bDnH@RLbdn3SLIeJPWWbXlvPW3JsiTraflxfCiKlChRJE1Sz318kcEM0p2kMdN9Ox3cTrpz7830YAJMfwh6ZoBuJMAA018b@RHnazCY@w/urCqSetiy9z5J0xZZrFq1atWqVatWFReLPc4Y/u53B/hANVVeDmTVRKZgmKivSzNBD6LMEn3iJCMaClMUhkrrg@lEUEzjmDpALEKSwkt9uEemOhYUaSXoEB9CSNPVgc5NkDnkTCQYPKcJBlKnpjY1kSruzxZGKD9RR1IA55xIygDATEHXdMEk6RGEWorMTXp97kVK9EWBmg7pBsoJ8g@TH0zEq5MJp/QNgIwhlKtm8uX0CwxxhK5U3RAwHl4wDBVHJhBa5AX@BWgSQDldUsvpyvmLJJZB50A6p8nCAnE9w9Q53pRUBSexqFFpNWovc4RQu1ko7MQSRtd0tT/lMRPMoQDJmHGiJAsGxUMFz5BmN1cQB9AB0gWub4FRoqojnAVNxjKSEK9pqCdzwyCPZAlgC0wCCZjPaAXp8tBAC20CGAx1ImzTYSBFEPrI0AReEiWelI6EhSkoBlTJCCKJH6O5JMuoL8iQYUMS7wdkaGpsRVkEBKm@SiE4eO1FBdZ3hwLAKILDBEEDVmMmqLhlgCMOL@Y6p2lAJPCwAYSb0gQETDLdBhI4Q8IiDFkMQekT/mlr4VYRp2zXEs0kDnFA71QnuA1Bxy0WJHjRUNAFQMmtxcsz1yUTWIDZm0Y1gdNRUxcE766g7xQJham4BBNXJEia7/TUna8W3NCMVo4gp5nUgR5uXpcoDgVT6PDxBH4pl@uEyldy6PPhPQ5bcg1NrekezotSP0cGfX8vwG/B9uiB/kwBVgq4IiNa1UyaC2hAYMAEAmkOB3EoMAsFNXmrYHT6oi22hMuC6kNroKKC2n5SM36q67jvbpjKjaHSsqoMgJ9QWX2qYH4oKMZAE/AqdD0/EmbANVWx2kidEw43hxI0moGbZKu3WBqIMBR0EMiezVGnXEOVpwQOchomFkDgCmTFGIsiaiORk2ScBdIxKotqXTCmsonzTJU@bnnQMEI/iBwyeLWPgSbqDIrjACmJgL402eqBhCgAhoZQSVVx0o//4s/7gwHgSfO8qvdtcW2jvsoTXckRYkEBISywqsLJhCyA8@PSrexQwIyTpT5n4uKVpV0EIYKUOlench@pUKA@l6BrDbkZdEdRFHhTsITcUq9@NOHGlt6QLMmFik@4HjQsKYCUTaodQJ@y0Eq8QB0QmQlMpqaYQAEtj9wG/Z3n47Hn44d7AYjzBr1HhzQ9OAGBCx6RKLhzvyc57fSO@jNMzlClPqUtzaGqhFCARy4@pWqC4nHv4HD73XrP7Q1ifebxnkgpPihKSt/jBhnPQLlu7wmf4u@k44eTF7m3SwQsc4wF91bBw3tdFGgc0idm9ISTlKC2RO2AHdpKU41HzHGcHNyKxnx5GTezIg7I6ILFUsXyAWooaMiCoHmYIOvFWgLD7a02TthX0Rc47AofSw8@94Hbt111ggFqulNR3Febkoq1lqwNp6CjgSmKoYH21rHo8hwIj4GVuAlDvB/1iFgTzQ@KhajEueDWBdQDPeqIEemRVo/D@QNYT9oYNj3Igdvt0EJ/qz@DLoAubRqvlLKszqFgQhsevkCDKLhwbgBNBJmtCqWtClklkpjdqo0V0CsYW09AiUBPgr6Aex2odlv0t@oI4OGQBQPYrL6ypYIm3BKw8NaQuOk3SBKhS01AS@hLxAtY9YAOEqxxBRcyJd3QAOMGmzlMIBSN7na1Vz3N1Ol04BZ09Yp@t0Phym/3KaxvkCjMkcwpgyk3wPaVAlk4nhc009ZXUBPDBI30ctghkQF7DA0aQ@rw08uyyVhij65bZWBdb7WePSJyWMnYFlZABp2KONtGRH1JB@0kL1@WDgCzF4W7vscgOwR873qDBMcQACETFgI/NUG5gSDPhxI/BNnF1CmWerTGopfFQ9R26aDgA@K6aEwMe/ZtiArS6yhMxpsoArhFX@OBMRajOtuJII2/HfE@Zs6Y7EGsrkmE8WArNkhzQZC9L@CcqIq6Bykwco0Wg@ymWO0ABlkDG4MwfjnWF@msawtx3UTQZqA9oOeD/A1NUzOOYbiQzOG0FwRJoZv6smhWFSwstKkvJVO1wj1Z7YF6NqB/0k4JND/tSYsXFSJx6zYcGdQM7DDRQCkYwJ@mIHUet2iA4iTxWQy8leQiCpygsM4uACRAQWCURzSISi6AUmksFd7jCpKuFIRO5/IjF@64Li8EcK41X7LqBGsh1CH2ATb4MjpoLhG0la37iern9o546zGAmHdud3CkSorns/vDhw/uY/cZaPgPHz5C6BSHPuKQD0IfSShAQhguiEMkh5@EcOodyYHjHtzPdw7mhfcBN9sCj04rSfNwd8fH4Qc/d8fa1xC@ekHVgWYD6AC@AB63N5XCQa/XdTaHigZ7olX7usXZPpGGuqAMKGGhqbqJKtVc/rGWbl6kXPTU0GlZ6tEKjK@PE@jBMJdx7ckPkxInOwTrqmqmSIPheAJdACB7ZkeZ6hT6PMw/pIlkFsnsR1awYG8azUnNQrkbBDVJMCl7NNrIOp4IbdoG6kHgi9tzIlFXJ2sNZ1ACP1SR6zDswrb8zuQVD/t2agSnTu2p61Z8HMdP8LQzyFMDnkcB1bpdR9qACQyIp6JBmMxRA58PQ5Kp6TrShkwSlHh6GtR7TuRnlnnG8eu56dY4so1xX/rbmdbIWYLcUKaGtlW5z2yIxM9MUcRdlLByz9zbBo9h2L7aE@RFLBIQZDFoLlZBrEViEcq6oED/LYg9eanFal8GygSVEFiILxI4nbIobMLQVoaZDCpLBlmq2G59at1v7imX1a/Du4OWa5MS2liY@81i1zYWIuMgN2MVa9FN6BFswOgOCpjVv84pSsaQnHZAX1H0OoXkNiY9kZz2ABzbphb0FDzvxywp4VkjtvZUFSnCnICRQYMgA1ZJCkfXyQUPH/vo2R0Id4jpCeIUZpJ0T1Jw@AtggWSCQIq9nvQWKPAFk@5c94Dp094@toFwDV/ZSmiH8eZUN2Whb1//6@/3oQFeN8@QW8IMiB@vA4/AN9xUAfHN1rKz4hty2t@yBGY0lSWOsIGEvoSS5/AslZPXgf2osaZGgcCQ06Fxl07jgnDiE3Tpd@TMolwX5GlfcK77CyEs3rXIrNyKNCE1gis2L8nw@kb2F/aklR/P8nVZ5foEi7X6Igmb1rbaRVhwA6gcvaWRQHF@BZ2O2Yc2yy1g35hT64xXWL7UrpKGf/u5crwrZEyU67ECzE65nvQGHzEZsbck2@ow2CIJiDI3toKPOLi/slZ1dGkwAEvMvr4FBmY3zIw0jhfoObm8IxbOGIHI@M@9h1OXrfNbIM4K8jrwFiBUVSannyJ8RBx46CFYdvA6Z2CLTdILxspcb4ktt@FPlyJcIBl8QcmkeJ@PCeNxeD0x3qyoatrb@bHhQPInk/tzW4uvBAGviqIgfKnnwugjTTg5EOpvBd9UxI6luwntAR1xMw5sYJkzQEhMm83CDJqFnN4TXDyg8FhcNqF3xHZDjrP@8dYUepNHk3hVlgyNNLdz85ZGfDn52KDBy@vktMmK717ztw/2Ph6sA@vQ/k6t8iaexr4hR1@hpKwZJJ6jbwlGUH2Ld7w6x783zYShOhOs8/6Ba7WXqq9QQQGZSAbMIV9n7/NfEle8HkpO@7k43kuVyct744/RlarqQ0ExUCjIYDNHIYv4MGzLsjWlbRarb8u0IcmqgRrk/B4vYJ5gGNZ5vzRvs03ilAA/tPrYOrw/216iyCCH0uT8RuNy8kCVY4kBzcHpTQmY6iLW9Pb1azXcWkOx7Bc11NroURXWvr6p2sfw/yXhIMuzOl612Aq@Y0vtU2f2bPftCsK8AC9F7q9cgUmQnEHamty91QA6P5xzS@f6Dxg93uKuM3poS2Iyg02HMyQTEDB1y4z@h5QWeb@0/tfpqFdo41@qxFbjjmUBNDY5v2pSFGLYn5iDZZiv11iiPBWmwl4NUu2NBBCb93TH1xPF2NU4tJdDaGAefnK7hlrZE8KvohqP5/juXYXDyRJ08i9aM3tVjQZ2toYn0DUI1HDgdcaBMtV2GneLd/WpUn@fc0PN6dlqf4dInPJTNVLiyzbTjiluCOT3ltmen6gw7VUnYEMoX9H@NlKycmSddxCTmA3mkYQXsfR38R6j9fIm2K9gj0CrSmMjgFfCvk7xhN6arxPgZBJmZIpgLvH5LW7vU6Q9VZV/SuuAPu1L2EwD4xO7MHyplV7ZPvZKN9qsTBh4laMnvrUmYY019uQRuIcnym82dA2qZJLB4Wta@dXS4Duj1tZC4ZfmkDBik4UfQ@ed8Fv01nHnZoOJYPxdgp1VMdoJvIcsGQx/jX2kOUYvWYfFa7fWau3GB@Pghf7RlsApqR8w@KEwEcjtOxY/1x9NDefyJtBCxb89yUGarKS@kU@ToMMr@LyzMrxlEpmqIhi0yekDAc9VZIEDa9SKfUvJOgu0e5lbnHADofBFydosO@BnoLwu7QT3L0AcW48leMj2BTViTQNVZSwsDee631he8tCe08m72PZ1ch6vbn6xVwfpvYvSX7D5lKE6VIbCUCc9Y333Vt8AiTQtn633KgH0DzljjB/6EoW0meMNjW3uyqosfw13sUK01KOq7l94zWNnqz5k/Ul4l1wPEuzLF9foYNwmTCID@Ft9ZyhMYXgyVFPVhAC5ewtUxis81nn/WnKx6jZQRxL0Pq4JlsUJFC31ZAHNJSBhZGw/Hdi/etSTVQ77FbxjwQNnnOvXrEfxqr7fkjvnVBOM0/dH3AKh50vjckYysQ/A4AuAO83TEzhTkca03b/t2/1yvKttSdUkFMjh6KAsATP0ZRC3cmo7vYEvxf09WyrbvpbvVis71fXll6XSHE6tJX0ceGtpxX5WtJecbKP8Xin2k0TiebZ2TjD8tsscxEm67SBlrL0QD4oKrwvEVcF5dI0OsAPFdDKVOVPVg4jAeTycz@f1UlYmvE4xUADMgSJ@YNg5xHIxM5AsGSaBlUR0d4cOPy@OmWP2GaWQ69iFHh4srMRNIb/QiANX3cp6d8g9pA7dgYD70H2vHCPGTUAFGaaNe0G5HThRIheLzk3VkcJNiD8KDjs1PbGcXowh8SsDwexDV2mB3UPWuFTdct2w/IOa@OHGf/mrvu1uBwOdgSaSAdOEgYJdRNWJMFTnH61y7dLTmsZhdz2MYz7Eq/e49EA2jQzo6DCwEy87dY5ahWbCdtqxnVjhpoaHty0qrEbFJhd2JTOtRrOo6auCJRZ2wetcTqV4VZ5OFFAvfXNoBFEDlI5AnILWj3EhhMEUU8c6tu9HRdQX8LJyHxNGzApZVcfk@TSm5L/8leWqBIkSFiEcdoonnopbJSJsKhH/IJ5Xp0C1g2Ql6KoN4sFMhqFtii12EGrBivcifsgRHyqQxIDjQYSLsbyIsukGCuSRG3vaYr@EE0n0HKbr5@075iH1czShhf/6@7T3s803188C8Zjh8iMH5OQZy9V2chSSN6lu5DpcuOxqYZ9O4sK4Firbm9uDw6S5HI@gCXEHJXInzIlHEHnQruCRG/tZKgb0D7j1EtRWp0kdeqaWeRhomCiK3ZHB4uIgZDmQEs867N2Csxwu0A9oiGUlwCM2ysCdxRAZO1RNUhnn0WB4@@ktnRN6U/IkYxYKhsIpUp3Dx9TpGQnpQl/F/o13390vQkzgfhHPP9CGw5z7@8XPmNANcE@FkevwWxp3oHwl9/kweMb88IPBLZHL9ew@sZ5mQy8//Fwr1vKNZrrZagA3n63KHhRUfcJtNAWWBU3meOg@MnEcBbbokmB8WXusNcj6DsA9HnTIoVPsh@71rhPWoDarXQHXoRVcg4AJt537C9n35TeErfTXALZmEiVka1FUI4Jky4zb2Nagfke2cLvg7j4Fne1wBLsW7FGFhEculAIuBYBLX8kj9LqWVgt@JBHQjF9m1Ps49qEAXm0gXgNgJq3LwvW10q3K7a3883@DGmswrv1ja0xwvFtjDPFejQFwk43kKKSL5VY9v5sJxGnzlgCYyTp@I0QkfcvyN7akS7V9Wx3NRCxMw/ZhW@tWA80kg1igWN5EPDLAJI50R/JA08DaBWFFFkRp2QBN3u@DauotTazZQKUHiROL5ckSUJDrAJgVXA@0fuSiMKyReu3jCJprzoMW@97KfEjgCGaD2uOTfS/QP/6LP7f8sO9NCP@hHV4wGbj7Y/tOhPA/d1JYFu7@5fouBHe/sO6@ozErX3udWrVZMxEzsF2sIYMYyZhFE26xVXs8tuGxU1LAsJMmwOsZYR0Gt6q14cwGj@euDZyH5gK2YyWN9TIpT9AfPNhn8JimsSmClzWCxGVCWPDEfCYuhE9T7EEPQwkdi8YiLFiVQmDmIAxIFsKAZiH0eo9BKqmZpKW@7/Ho9PQUuQyek4VU7MRiOX3IfRd2fb8m9BBgKctquUOQB7JsckDamZ3Nc8j5WC/Oijunm3WjhxMwSKwWhDHNQwIA4sXRis0PFwyaqs0qEA9FWJhE8S8dawxMIYW4ggnWexQOogAgsnBjR@@XUr55Eo89lLbkPrjdDK4OBmtgsGPXPiG7@w7dm/fKg@3vj0Bgfr1H5BQI/9GelwDW0pN@7X7ueek8jmuDPjUUFXtnFIBa5AnRoTDNxrxbfcplowJ6cQ/6AVBCn4E@yAvSSNWMdDZfLFVrjVfu0wTS/RLMjdxnp777QNB/97AOuF9IvcPUTIFuXGUKDiu3qdoscGKIzSrnSzL3lfaS0jdK71guEK/LJgmvCmKZr0VMVhQCBfIg4DX2TSq9BZi1HtG@KtXj/fx893B6dq8cvCr@h31vlhwEj7BwQejeIO@VuNEenVN0HDua@B1BI@h4CoZcm/em1m6T1v0m@m0H6PUbhxsvaMeFBHtAh87ovjCjlaksU8E3nEug7kHaKoq4AFuEOfSCrnFIZTGpmwJ56tUi9TY1yK7L65cjbU/QNZOq1kSWvOHBKTCH0SXegjaIgramu@R1BJjwFM3NHAnmXXhhkUwFl2TaA6pi/cC7L5HlNU53vDjXKQ1hIgWaDj1YcWy8mkGRYW/dIdRNlnonXOpugdaOku85PAcNTZZMD/Y0XgTxdBJq4/HiCrCnsoAdlU@TD7ZXNHKcl33E/7k2BX7VVA1tpvA5wQnVYRaHclNADmIgoNJ0AnAiudQFPEoIqKIGIDPw0e0QcQeleOw6BCf9KJQeHAqLvjSAkcbj9YNK@hnLbjynOa8Ppt5u0MMWq87xk/xtxvwkb@8tjnF3XFBS@sLCg9/sOX7A3IF497wzc3tdr2SAuJzb/uf9l77njrLgTLvXbvy2XyiEZHKtCHb7TjIZHBoUdmSFGQiU2DD1MgRhDPWIE05Dnilx3jdQEJFbz71H8Rum7kWBMzyezZGCfD4yd4ELSQgiklMkIUnGS2ce/Mqbh05BO@NYQ@njy0rS0B0bDD5AmBTiRYd49SEL5gaet3spME0hyzFBCwMw/B1jiuYwS8MUWddDUiyFlw50gNqbTDryYEg6IPCC1BqdfYs22mDTAy2uJpPHdmvsqsMkArE43aMxAO0eNefYpsBf2xsRuIaVGEBlYVIqgUL5dCkoCvRXD8jMBHon4qYgZLrX77yc7d@8ykdKOLBIvLDdG4HQ3Vf88u7Psgr2zCF9QmbAJ88w7n9/jwd@0R76l/Tv0UH65LPnUE4taTDGvGeew2GK9YWPfL5D5chzqGBz5Ntv8cT5@RCsncegK@haAFDgUPaegDyDdZQ6VE4OuVPPYT8VOiI54Nbn836GDD836ODnQ@6ZPvwWrAk/xOhW7/QcGl7cHZhgkH0G@nAPOaT9IDOfPS7kIq9W4@IPJZ8P0xA8fMQE/Jy@b/jIuHLfoMkc/cQ2cunBxFEju7bKuiVevSpuMdCOPl5r9ChxU7eeYD06wNtv@O1J22cf/e53B2wMplsfY2GP6vsYZU587ih74j5AB59c9JFLd32@zwVmSAi47zgxFHx6qI1rtRvvvQdk032QrbrYiOu7I5o6oI@YH@I0/f3334MRiu7OgmfBB@9dwP1w53EmUmfx@JE/ljjyf3I/bs/cvJ5QyAusur@Pc9yRLxL6pJzk8fF3/@ff/fLv/oT8/ZL8/kaSJM3o9@GnDtEYreAYiwj/k/CqvxXmcLgnrjxgv4NZl8Ii9w0cbM3tjobdje/wuysfP8Af@YdjfYvPH0iMHU1AXh8fEHVwxh@sDliWPViSv0ccJsfCPgKLdw@aZUP33@B9B2IfPn0DvBN85Dg@/rRhEe2KJ1yqSmKGUEIUqQfYwN8ciwA@qINFk8N/qNnDf3UT/7XH@K/O4z8UyIzxX3mF//YRRB38PJXyvXugPXHB4KMTog6@P/0@9Y84cH2oA5jtHJydPTw/@wJ3we98Jyf2P@iJk/UdPqwQEPDgC/hO705Pg2dni7PAw9kddfAZWPJMHYRcIM73R9RBanFaJ1Te5c6c2uwcZYg5DTzc1cpgqDf9odPAQaiQzvpDjVbmgIW76OYWJ4bxbT2fzlVbAF0r59ON/HmxnW/VIN54eDz79MkXhKb5BPw5ewCKFj/znflSpmmi28ejIPqK43FPyLqlDnJnixYdOAWiy9RBnZQUCD6ePfxAHdwd3Hl8H30fGZmZMeyYHV@p1c1/tbpYRKqx6icE6dKCGak6M2SGbB9EFzFCi1kyywUzUatsH4IC/DETCEqMuGAGjMIoLLuD7@3/SVW9qqqASoVs5oIxMVZGhOugWr0CZCIUPII/iWGYBRC6YGbwz8hWP/rukcFKgrm/p@6Q63sBVEyQdQcZdzDmdksP0Zj29Pk5FHu6I3ZINPlwJywk88GF/O7H@7tkMul@ODmgjft72lK@rlDEdYJBnp8fH3PpZvrxkcYLOIvTQ98nX@ATHKkz36l9@XjQPzv5eH8cwOJtiXjw8YA@/Xh/Fg7gcMwHHA9B3Cnt@4nHBiVcP9xTbs@80@ngX2c@m1shErDi7jvrVHzq0BBlhXAUHBiU3pd/N7B4LWEez1304fOz1@u9d5@4LT55PEgA293jYu8XIRGFXF5i1CdhRGTD2O6KRb1nZ7Eo3McS3oCHIclWlnuXpmn3riBZJAgS16xUKq3r3JIARWBQvndx@uO96y70kEoloyQ6GkjGkKoHkmGvy@v9jj09tcsIeSHa5V64VN2NPj9v/3k@P596yOHFf14vjrTPZ14PJHujcLf47Fmcek49OA6icK7Pz2c4SOA@Q@jO433wPj9bcXD2eE8tnGdeYBteCflv@K8ayNCQ@@D5ABtTCopEvZ7eUvBGYp6EL2n/pT5ABTyusDsM9XK5Offd3aej8FE8cvfx4Sh4hH@e0/uzhz1K3AtDOHQYR8BT7AFmH3UQPKm72JDLjQX@BD8DUWUhKKsDFE6egLWZPKEOIJsLjgOQR@RBp2enayHZDDbeM@iRnxHhGvI@IO/zZxAcKxGMLY/9vOL@fsEwZIhHJ73U4ecD7vmE4EfPLgfclj@C3@M@IQ@0XJ9dh5x@xz64nl2Hn3vP2Co9Yr3E@IlGTk6OIlY4noAwe@S11mjBejlZhyFFMDiedPSTAywfbmCiF2qV6gkDSQFLdLsD@KLR6Ac6BJfFz2L50OLIPs6O9hyJUMJ35Pt0dwRGEG6KBxL7wwfqBD8tsh5NuQIuqxuhRJIQcYAMI4lAn50KhzXfwvk7yh1ZIRb/8h8MCiZUPRCROYozMMTL@P0UVRQ/WPEwM0Q9QQDjXJBlvL6JJ04wf5D7c5isf6AOoA2BKkiGY1LjhKkgzKfTubA@spJxzI1GMO/Hx4@//oMff/0//vibX/z4mz/48Te//O2vfvkH8Psr@P3Cuv7iPySj@PzbX/3L//XHv/gNRP4N/P4z/P7Tb3/1b37f@pH7v4Xf/70V97f2bwvO@lGA649/@6s/@cvf/uqf/xn8/p39@7OXvx//9D9a//@P/YeDv/nxT/8Wn@ybP/gF9fd//Wv8/yd//ff/@df4/3/7X/7@r//13//xvyeBP7cC/@@/@w/WGQr/5R/9@G/@GdTpT3H4n0IY/pEvYB0@G@APceQPhwwDo@H9D9uQP9AsjFOI3or8Q/TDPXaQZTeQgP/f/kAzMJQyFuQa5zbkH/32V//qLyH2BxiFWdaG/GdOdls2dyDXdGJrzyrrDwH4L7Zg/vDHX//@j3/5P/z46z//8dd/TLEIb5D1AX2gQghf8QlHkgAJLY6oaBi6gBNmN@FwhISjcN5nmOAHRx8/7URZuI/2ARPAjyT9w147B5dx5NC2r7APTv69GD6iT5AMoxsZ4Bb4jG8gBoeJWiQXJ2phA5J7C8a@38ppxVj3aCv7bjyO3MroXPZFWwmkSAcI2cgWdqFog96uBuVQZgEvXkVQyK4eRcVRqwanevH8orl1bebT2QsqhjLVSu7FJWoDRVE5X2iub@NWqpM1ukbRzZfLL2/tS1c9Pk79nI3EKbjC3RTxHFZWZJuMBdnIKnh6CqJOUWefA6en1Fkj34SEZhWxISZInd2gRRDVateBZ@oMr/akLCXKRmKfA4ZBUVjDfkDRuN8fDAbhhK9@cpBr8PA7B4R927Y@cLEMG3W5YigUd7lAjQY@upYCGqIJCqMTDeilrvBTjyRruatIGCWEdCGJH9CDWp4rxD@ih3damWpvR8IFR@GgLg2GJjLn6hrAMAyw2tb2nGPLrW26DupxHP791ANKELYP8/0I0yqDxL1KkV@DUxcwOk3wlgfYd87E039JRAwVxC0VCiUT0UQyHEr4E8lEJMrGolE/G/Kz8UQ8yfiB8Qk2logmWX8ikgxHIpGkH5o@moxTB4LSl0SahlkaC9M1fJUUHr@ze4pfflaDwzPqoC@I2JUDLTx9LzroryOmCeQKJ@4ZBBldbIzCj1WPFikw9vED5zCLWBfl4hCPDgqFLFMouFwZfAOanMkyLlcf30QTDBPPuFwCSckmwkwIMg3xXT7G4BcgXBK@yaYLBYxhhG9CCYzD5RpbKdaN7NzEAUzBN@EwRoBcrqc1OgaQqxZFCZLLtG4YJpN1uaYWeQn4A7i0dRchxObxDU7AmQpWShbSXK5zJxMMUC5X3YKzi7pw6ptOu1xF6yadxihKpPJRq1KX@CZNDsikwx0Ir8s1gMBAB8vD5epBEIuwy8VDiF9yEDeBEHYYVkzO5Vpa9cA1cbkWBJrjxy7XoxMP5QA9Fxfc0OwLA@tY6taVh6QiJEmLab7QOz/vDQY9fZnOn9dJUql0wY2WU7036NkZe49wqDgXJI0ny5eHgJMeHzl5f9IlJCkvkh6XjwKh8JF7AsrsY4ALmjyWcFIJkvYtntgI4ZgAcA8fmQlcM1zPSnIOkkSui17PdQJCS@Heg5Ye72cykfUgQ1oJoHQ8jH8K86vox2nCFYu7jo/g6vroCkNw4UGMGwxsl/ve5fLeJR8@uuJR17H748eA@1v2I3LFk65jVzzuQt4TXTCnuoJCJ8@4nFWKOcHXJw8@c3587mFD/bMN1zt5xuoXrPvPT56VL8X6V96PmDCYD8IE2nsMhJ480/Qp7v24u8IVOSqbLM8DXMIVAD2O1gCWmlj3cxQIgBJH8ANbBqdrKavOHlfSg2cjQFAyee8i8wdr4dTjdsdDbrfXfQJIPiCXF2YRFp2YdkKfU3us46H2SZi42pX3JAMwrUKBJFD@ihZ9fGyYnI6X0ElRx8gVS7pwNN69MflqDPnkD7D@46Ne9PTsn7w6/rt/su/YH4sPyhrlYix18Ez18Vu/kSQ6wbOxzxTMZE/P7EIv0XLJ@QIODd8iNPAdUoduzAJ3eGdin06lB/W0M8lKZ6mDQFiNqAeHh4fUwWnzzBV2VYOP60WLM5qse93jRTG8iBS8fzz94PsHrWgEgmefnNU7IJymdAF7lPXx3pHWykIiiptkgIwD3z/wgEKoFOCkTvBU1XWA@x4vQ/@L45ccrQqd/vyArDyg2mdxqpBHisdX@AGShztukI0Y7h5Aan5ekeTPiXDgjCzBY6kG4XjWGsnv4t8lvrtqVVvVwifmOHGcIJy8v7eb38@6WTdpmcdPMIBJ9Tx1YPygRtmfK6WTg2PNHY64w@vmuE8dWHVn496Ds1A8aHDLgwfbO9YTgcgH62lJiD3o7B7znZsZWbaEohK/1x8MpNDvXX3/wyFNu93rog7PPn/F8Xx3evp8io9nO4BPz8/Pp6/@yWVzvAGzSf@HiU3w8eDh54FT6/8UTtmqxRxXLOryYn9n47vH7x4PQJ0kkSsUdeEZA21NYzXHNjlSyJ9gHOG/7zYRR5D9aH0nnJ5BsoDuvUc0TV@HwGhJJmOJ2AH1O5p@7@E/pK6fhomCoBvTyb7HYWlduuLwo0Jl/UgMAlfTlaDD1dmF0jFvELZv8PNebOBsx9k2z1YU2bx1N25p0Ng5EceCeYy3@SRbBSMR61IPXuMxiZMZOsJb52IfbC/1mfoGcE15k/g1wumEor7BDnb41uPA@dG3hunFLkWMl/rmG3tkMMygYT5i5DiTHRlgT6hnCrOH6/cNhJ9UEg8hy3Gbw@5qqma9RicvkZXJICOcZakRn2tc7hbBR0i0qIDaHCFSIqEcV84q/hsLrDcVMSmFYjkPeVAKieSJt53bpffwJmmkeh9Er104YiAKY8HghFMEHAMCOoj0ENzeCfYO5z0E0odYnC6SJ@cABYarn1DiR6Kd8Q7fPkB2jF7kZdUAxFbpHqsG6OjRLtaugzPg4koAC3HtyIhGBmZ9wPvt1sPby9w9eNFnxwfVg1PRKQptnGRtXNAY1v7GJCM/6VuCQ3afs9lMsLEPfmjaE8uX0bOGs2M2jHqmjkz/5MRqKu2EuvTw3s/4yerJzyfffst/p91NHk68k5SJrz7fBIbXsUeyQI7M1CQF4qHdSQ8n5p3PJz2kJt5LD773nkzADnmmRIvZhteuG9RcSQEt2PvC8PpXd0rg58qDv3Cn@IDkqf/oNrXycynGv4CfBLaJ7H9KsXY9oEwztfIpJ9wp/PBD3h0/UbAxfNzJThTOMvbIqdUd95ACfsiQ0ecrQGWATuNO9vkevFC4DImvM57I337L@eSzxYkcCHgx1Hfhj4U7EwIPvhS@P/Zwp4uPq7sp5D/2wDUFxcheIB7y2bx@XtMO9J0Aj6023ZBu0bjA5C2AvEkqdXT78ej2KPXhw@puEZg8@C32HzMbacDELzDxJ1t@uJ6jWy96wRKyWutx/Uw6/lnwyEAuv@TzAZP92lZOi8KjW0jRfD6H6mesL8m2q44DAZYw23fU2qWObFxF1vfJ7rAG2RHb7GMvesibNnhJssGt1x80CSbLHN7H1Y8UVQlwBAKn2dtA48T7xcePlFO07a4IJWPl0hMQhyfdZBdQHS8dky3FrXeXvqRf96lhR@eu55qN4m0ewbQ2HNvqrkQ1kQ5n6PwdBsFq4DPzfGJpLMtJFZQN0R4AQ7QHhgtgLYKZZOsJGzJlJ0JrOQ0EubCeEK13t/C@ZwbWT9gKXvd8UCEWGdCZ95Ah@UcpoptAniQIIemUlAcB6CrUN1AJTAOug/SAzkCRoW@/RfbtaQqm6nE8FmAwDDfysRjoFaVQ@FdQCjgwlSOQUawPSSFA2zc4BTth7xQU@ccVZL9D4YEMvpHfepUiSF6l8EwVw3qDCPPNa5GB2@Kbb0a@VMQmCP7J9ALyQ9rz7w7s4f4YZatXtVYzX79KN@AMs6PEZqfp4/WexK92ItXwDqM9SSGOxDxXZ4VuiUfIAyariXemwjuO91GpVUahUCXnx/tIAOsPrMU0GFCP15gEg@zRZwRVfUDPpbFE737AAO8OTXyWyecSAs5W0ZgcMjjLm/eaNq81GXjBCwZz@@X3nc3qJ4Jh2BusBpw968m@/OQNrwl@UQl6ob0hK3EHczxaiP8UfrrhJ155ujSQyEbkQwvBTn6yd6ZpZSf9g8IbqfY5k8MSTSUTDHOMGD8OsE4g5ATCTiDiBKJOIOYE4k4g4QSSdoB1MLMWZpjKhsOxTTC@CSY2weQ6GGE2wQ2GSGgTDG@CkU0wugluSousS4slCF504HCTdF1Bx2lsJOGk4fcSFZNERgEN@zIyAoSGXkFC9sirSCgvsRsZTzJ2QUW6ioFCodjmHrSPA5vyWFT5LTr8VsnWnR0JYxVlTdGIwOZ1HbRSfoF3jgah8x4j/J4GRYHaRbwscGAMCCZYKakCyL/gPbbeX9SXx5t3NTCGFLu@h@x4Z1XIw5JN0C3x2ZMc2pdsYQvtxWa9AIrWjNl60cUm0qLyeGektTBGduK2sX7AChZz9A2IkAWB22D3zRinzKY@3Vtk@P0idxDuLfIVURbe6L5cmDcegjzlZCXjP8GWcsqz7BSBtDaYAfYXL4gMvGhQ/CJr6jN77Prtr/7sf0e//dWf/Ab9@Be/@f/@0/@Mw/8Rn/4PsFlQaA3wiz/Bp3@LT/8an/4Cn/50KxOBDx@7fvyzX8Pt//Tv0Y9/8CdW0r/6S5c/skYEKThqk/OX/xSf/hk@/V8uf3QN@Ms/sgBxFpf/mdoxrTwA9Yu/QQhKw1jWyP7srxBy@cDA8NiSd2f18Yet194sBGs23JHQw8t068wPdcx2xutzAV77jt3c@XADeLeQ6xz@hMOm74E5YzlRYy3Nc/wQv9pkR6kGtn94bMKoRnAA8jbvg9Fjr2q4ofb/PTpGbh@GgWjy/m7K0uF2/e16uzapGNbnooE6vCuyjQqHvWtKYHpLgXyTmcDSCOJpC5mRspaM2Pyt4E/EOAOIy5EsyfSwXsouy8kNkx5k77QP/5upLhZaPAxZ77@SL15Q9rs37FaBO@rmRbNBKS9jYMq4eSNuOyuJECYaNAlkW/MbMxbfEC74X6LbtJzdbfLVwosOg48emJjjbY20LiiFXK4vwGJO2/BebHGFd@Etem2AO@Y4/LDzft0@YNfNzY2L2opjsAzpfQ/BsFUpS2Wsk9jdpNBWUmgrCWi2cBJdEw2FXtBABg6sF3ffJbWybamo3Wwb4cI9x2kHTAbMBa3FTL8oT41h6jVqopF3ld1r5Fso2YeU3U/uFaJzzpDL@yoD4NzNk3rZlvtRM69gXjfU/pyY2zsxO631NqadPFudgnCPesmldcuxyX0tt1vgO6jZB99XFhRi/pEFBb6yoFj0ywW9bFacdwf92/z9stpx1MRaw2@QWR3/YGeAwkPjn4HobdQRplgnQY8Xpjxpe8rTm6vIs@eTChBPOxtH7XxHQd/aTgpPYiqqKVjLA580FaYcKraCt77DtO8La/ZnjwaKqgvG9nuzkvVmkeLGb27z6kCBUc2PN7CS7I@E4Efw1h4du@PKemSzrdCs9WknjNpiFLY8Hx8lRTIfH8H4lEXvhoH4Nsjj1z3cFP4mFIS28nvWpm1V86h4Iz7T@2WcxN61sjUlfuypanaiGwpJI5jQ8YIMky805Pgx/roZYQmuInk3FVukPdPjxUwcqhN1ICgqfmkd536BvrjBjQniNI3Q4kecH/FbFNmTaA/v57x21sufnBVdhjycd50/tItghxl@pL/kMeasvqe4xzeLs7I55TV@Or2NbXob79MrSrphvqSZROLVHnz9aUWHPRsMALghI/xlMvz2PhWvyNkhZR2NP1ViZfhqEvuCwcPwhylNA2jaBg@KIB/@9Z0Bd2vC22/x//0GdLLnv7b5iDHbWIK@meSx7UemaAbZpUfhBQ@AF71Y97wubi3aua8sy57okBmeH7mI4lLwW0PQMTVNUAyXA@kg/oLMY9@gV3JPHIZSVuIemvSZH41DbzdR7rEvyNxS6HtsSP8WXqfGdYHrE331dRXHio4oPdX6Po2H8bM7phh5u5MAHb8hMpx/5vW@LVYWiLSWHvIwjlBYfJt/ZOHupWrGi6Ap6xmIqoMGPSAbwJBtd7SltrTeCJetz@LZetQaf6yWrOAX5b/IEOCD9dEz1r8p1vue@qx71lX6ihFhDRvcrTJ@6dPBiF@7fN2GP41FX64pWWVYZ0o5rbxjnbzV4tJ7Lb4lFY5MWlbJ14nkl4Tuq2VuS9QsZBsVlv1pQ8grzFlOlnnes43Rinm3xVTllU7AcbjFVOWNUeVxj0Jd5ySazsQfEkhZ9oWXkiBYhOsMrm24YoQwB320BMqpG7ZrnSUvkjLhtC2rxY6547EtusVF7/ZzxC0oygnjhdzndZn8m2Xyr8rkd8pc94DdIreAKH6nSLsVcPO81wSyIJpvaGechGfucHlPbcOhqJyOn71@dkvuY8mP3DP3MShkt@A@zntAKbv77uMcCRju4wYJjN3HlxDY9C33D@5jp1tgAB1uSeATjrdVOL7n3cdZj/eZIh9DdcoNuo/XbQowH61bwpFna3m1Zz/1V9erqoLgt4xKP8ISY8BFxdW6e/CTHwP/BNTeVQ0SP6RQ6IgA4wnIzqCxNWJY5cCwESRfW/TsGz6OnaUpe31js4YC6b7U1qIKlpIp0UfuA/euMrIIw6lk8RGuQCDWm8f7KULsq5nZl8ixSwcJJY28Wz7hXpDYA30PSb8D4O1FHHmT32mvXRRWA34dnTjzW3S@IscpjlCEnQG8e8jCTP3e/U6lcFu/2KHLav3tFnq9RoAbMeCAWK1E0G7pdLDhsG1KCtNUbVdISCp@2idt58GH3Smx9L7IRrSC3TPfSCbRds2wYtju/N73qrOVD5O2o4Jw4h3zYPWy9bhAdDFO2ui6LUvV6nxAwpbO6ZMtMwQstjk7SOAsdeMnY8Vbw5CT1yqSaK5dNQmZg/jFvSlnWqVvnsvg1/l@2vTVyQkmONCIEWzlXJdi6Vf1J9jvqmW/Owa1w4QXBewzrPcPpa/N63dH2ReUy5tiXzcgTvSjnHevcbQuYcNymB1sWebvydorEx9/X8oy8q1C19hfWPsO29Zzgi/w7eXcwsKFrQR9ths5xguz49DbjHptkcizoGO0BHFJNh6r4mtKN1V7n1ar4vuaGKfgMRouP7mB9d0G3m48jI9UQH/BcquX4893kucU676N19S3nlxYTx1U7CW23m9uKxLUPfFfW7toQUT1sZ6rVspdGHTj8bj39aMI3Gsh72Ycp959TLCetoT8eMsg8lFx7DsxVHXzw73ieu1SRiLAGODIcxtL/Ow@7rV12ZY@f9F3IZ8Fu8VRG9d40w24Ha2ETR0OD9mSzVdrb3PPEWcjccxb4LefzNbwUyMsHfiBzuMjGb4eH7FzzuOjPYrhplk/Rvrdgf15s9DWl8EPdr2ZiMVlvNqXAy8ATCfWd6ntBTh7xw3LD@UAfwPedHKvc00VU3KcHfD6EH5EtfaM8IRZr/XpeCfG@sI7SKonFMFT2FAUvwdt5cLQeOGTuFba5XywDB288ayhqYr9CfixoBCzHW@DazhLr4TsqTLniBuIVQp5fXuLIsshy3kuRr7qTHaTtz6hzSnWErLDGz8SBkHyxCeUhCnHWNKsHeXWrh@Gl2QiBBMfLeBxTxYm@MvKILt7VpOvJGiVYUEaDECQaHvDfsvBpYk/thxQxUDW2SnlALXJ97HtPTttnzCyX669Dgzs9OxsdWOgUAysqaQfOLv5AWOxmwzC29kwxEmLQMEvDpe4FUz4t/J@8Cy9u1dnDxDWi/F98DzilrXe55R0vDn/jFO2@Gy/5rm1NG0/tCR6YOvJpbNrE2XvspUizymD2EdN87gOXM5eVjhouU1wMu9sAuPB2w8dU98oRPFgDzDEW741YOAq2Ggjj9e8a5dUBf0MhUPka6NQHrFSSbGAw3qyt4Md0iArJtby7rMVjOtnfdfP8MNE6psDrAstWcP5HVHGYbJ750aW0QcbnfVABXdlqws4N9GtmzBMNb7ZU/AHj8sHWHwur2sHE8DbTz@@sTTv66ygFL2/o5v9WKegptPp5oTV6@fpQXqYrnfhPsOUfZ1RJE/T@Qu5n84Ve8tzNd6ciSGm2b3O9MK@Wry/0KSLSfZCy1NSpDvx3YYXyYvIKpoNZ9M8cyOel8VIPHsj3hhCWhaS9Gw0vu4Lda3H6oZ0Wbmq1Fd0oXXdHlyPxNtOZxRXGpRWv80MrhfCdaKjzNqtZNG4FtrZijmujMwpu6zGO7HWXDEy7WZmWFoW5@NFMaZ2pWj2Woi3Re1izi@jGn/Rom5nzWGscbEcJ9lJf5nOGv1u3Oeju9nMIHHB92/FUiN72R/o0V503Ehy4dmkJGrL4eWF8lQeZRsz3qeNCsXYjFJqxdlciHTGPflCua23271cpjYfs8at1h9FOldTs5fQY@HwNC0MR5FocWrqiXImfRk3c@liuyDftM3bZTtRo8wLsxlvlfik7JtVTT48zbVog2kvStJlYx67CDXVC6UkF0e18fn0vCZr03EuIlWbk4g@uCn01FDo4roxu@iWKT1S6nQT9VEokeMXPH0ZVdVJuJmslPWrxTTzVBU6Wb6REXoxJhO9ybOjq@qSr87K9XqnpnVak7hxycq3BWZEVW/4RjozLpQnCbZZWRYT58XGNJstLma9kDhQ09N@J3x1E5uXK0Kxc02HL7ipeeWTslWZHpVKxrLduizeVIxb6NZXJSkiLheZdkYXn3JZ46pepiv6eNiIjJS@1o5LWZUv1YoRszhOX8w7t8liZiyItd5YHTc7cmdqSrkRXaCW2fF1qyfMC9JqzuUj5fY1PcrXeTOeHoQb9EgUe2O5aqwG5@XVoDHtDfrJ6jmTE54u@5l2tJ7X2KuCEakoS6rbzIjSqn4tsuNa8qJ428unpSslmq0JWu38YrYIhbqSWJtHV@ziZlSISAs@wpSrmZsr33UpVPeVfZlMTQ1XB1QoVzjvDKKXPrUgrOiyyD3Fsz59Oo0sclP8Le1yS5H1SVRmEoWmbxg39E7y6mreM4o39WyHl1eJ26vxOHZbp25mRUPVQ4lSIZ2ka2NGP@dGleJtXFIKkXnmXM4ni51VK2Hmy1M5cVEe5Ep1Pdec8DfJ/KCxXI4HiZJQK4/TlJDI1euj3qDdW3QbRm3JXEX4Uc@XP89XngbQj9uNQqjUysQG03q4fZlTZrVmwbdSbzplLVsZs/laYhprxsMTarYoJdINU5G03PlVMnY9lcr5dG7QyrKqINw88ZfsmGs0l0zCiOvXhZtrzfCZzZ4a6Q0z4eX1VZdu3xpG9EKibhedWDE91vnL/sIsGfGmElKr1wx7LVZacnTWkZ66NXWUntCXrZsV3ZuvCouayZuNsRrtx6Pj84XxpK8u9Usq0R1xcquSVcsjPnbZlVZxOsoqzW5WvOK7pRCTbg0uroTCxWywagmT0OjiaXrBc7xRS3d753JsttB8YjgxK1PNSudmEH96YnpCpZuU0uNWvVY0Q02OnnYb5ehTuWsYBb5VlDIRSZnmMt3z8SR7u@SaxmI1bcZ6sris6SEmTy0q3as2P1IHRsG45Uerm8KtcjUNxW6qIzFu9sfsRGLLbZGJV7S6L@eryee9wTLWngozHixD7bqosZn0aFSlquwkPsssk4apnBuXlV62lJbS6XIidK2F4hfj7PnFoi@1W@3KRZ9TI7e9bDhW7Q2YUD9TyQ9qkckgXqvEI@Us1ewtr@tsP5eQ2CEnZ0elZURLlkOZGN2e1y@uR82hUpGz6c5CzIT5pjqPdzhRaQmrWJy@YnyjYbKkpJlILUa1zJzZKhfmYZ9yWbwK1ZZL/qbHTcOc@NQ1fHx3NVxV2wKnysPyU51ttqflrDQatWMZvslUMw1mujLmnFauUclcTWFz5cWsMB82Ooyh5S60RG9R6WdrNaGn9cOa2KumFyIz63Rur69bVWVycz25qMd71VWfG0XbpliPVRcm9QQmT3tWbhV6i5xoiKP67Ek5X0xv2nSkdT4pt/oz3yh5252FpZsqU65k2iI3LV4P4marstCuSrIo05NQdUBT81ZttTKFtJqvzK@6C7G9WqWljPHELi5prnxezN2YvmS@kM5Vmw1Ol6vV83IuzU3mV/PyTdwnrBpX/ag0frqlaooih/TbhhzPMGEj1IrmVll@dM5MzzOTZqmZZDW2ddG@urpkhzI/4ePdai7WueI76XTpclkSuXatptUuW02q6lNubm@bdLUpl5NiuVhvqtHiTL/qdOLcXE1fc0wxMunNy4vM/Go67UySJV/XFLiwuhIEtj6Xy7RwAbKToITprJat1Ixl6Gk1ehrMcupNO5nWzmPp7FLsz4TZiknnZj7aKCzm/ZikJULN7uJc7PJXg8FlPTMMazOtGctGqVJSvFLavezwKrkULi/K7cLUFBr9XkTyGYw2al6nW0aLX0rnfGw4axldGTqfqEWbmWzSkG9ziUtd8jEJPkPxnSuuRpeH0ZtKqa/Os4ur9jIHU44EK9aYqLpU2tPEWLm4NDKXnafLRGLQ6l2MoeDp8HbISy1fpt8TrkW5Qt3eXLbH@dq0TY@ub67itdaFL7EK6@dPvDo855LL5qrKMIKYHMyK00VYK/OJ88RllZdLi0q9JQqDWCN0LZ8rKyqnxIdMWmTns7lC@5bRTCI/EDOtiqLnWvxFXFBrHE0vOrdmtXOTuAydM9dMYzJnQsbVnGbEriItu5VuN9SnMjPjUus02Fned2Gmu41RnT@X6UqnXlypy3I@ZLTSlax4OZ0vtfJS0sO3fPk8K9d4iQWzJBobNPXWeJWZ9aiOuChnM4n4begCJMgw5OS8G@EE3tAGixFdvppeyIvRdNzWfZMFXffddhfR5LA9NGi@XG5WivO8HlVLxkihYjE@dNHRtbhRf5osi1kzN2y35Eg22R70qhdd@qopXiavs43buBCt0cUnIdlpxBi@HO3wNFtXJzMTRiR@MKbKS6av87Kgc/Fp9Sman059/eVsavq02/j5ZaIzGGfZGc/5wume@sQt2iWZkSpxYWBUO/PZTaEDFqLSnrUUqnDb0sKX0oXYuGhXr8ZsLV1fmXQm2eFvIoOuzoqKOKuHzWipKAzivJjL345HuYviU5Hpik/MnJX16@tw4YKl4qIvY6p9mW5fa9fKKsQJ6W41cTXvr7KTYUUULoqhnN6tx/qNS07OwzAqPZUZrV04L9/2e/KQFlWl2qgzDHUbC@U7N/Undta/rq2a6uJCH5TSNTl8IxYVtXbTZnPXOl2JZwrX2VH9NrtMxGq63BOag0RTmfjOwyrPpZVyjIoLMyHT7tAtQQqz8cWqx40Fmr3tjMeJC3oVM1Z0WjHmo8RgleydT9jObUU9by7H9PlkcVvL3LBTwceyNV6jrs1VLXp@3vFdLs9bxYHcKoo8zU2WI@MiMxVK8951LO1LaEzTl@@3h4tybaB18nS810uwjXC4EzGf@rWlcV2h2rnyRTieW5oLMT@eVhaJCy0daywXretIZHw7WlQTjVg9umBn6jif0QqDKK3eGHFl0bwYFDJCXrwSjatVj59QsdW0Uiwk8r6owHVr3VtGzNNPjb5sDgdi8/Im3IjRfPSiWpvf3ubS9CQujvJF@RzGxDl3tVg2Rt1x77pqhCVKrXZ9xdgqtmrcXlf6Sq1Tuhr25oN4vKZftEfJ6aqr1aW6T1u1ij31PFebyLnVDQhcrJ6MjlpyvtWRbnJ1pkqZsU56DjY4mylLywFdjDKXosKUFpPz5M2kExt3x@3srN5djEexRjyqToVV3Ow8RadCK94tTRo03@vOh77QOaU2Vsub/HVEL1fmWtmsqcIlkwiVb8etSX7a8k2yl4Weme0wWi/UKc@nvmwUrILEVTsZqvQuR5ni@PzauLgOJalmQVpOE6Pz2LmvBoPJdGRUE205JM/oDi235zNhPGG4So5r64teq1DuV/qhBK35pPjcvIw9lbq1W87UIgpNGctYf875LvJgQeSkbrTha5saM4G5CHMzC18qg3DIUG4aDd7MqvFxK5wUIgW9rajthTpqh6Tr8/h4zkuXIyojrPoRuVXv9CuL1byfHEf6XGPWShdulE44q2jDhaGzseRlqM091SZ6uGpqtXKLzyjXE44T576FnMld6Y0Z1R9U0v1O4WkqztqRajqSXt70mcj0djZildVNvhsa1XrpoTivdyKr@jyc6Z@zSn0iaRM9RDPNtpIfJxatC@GSKq3ywnKYuM7U2pHW5Sg5DsuDcaPGLMdVSeRvb40pW@wOytdsvxhtZ66T4wvRSAvxVlIsjehFpVe9jWX7QoShfMPihA5ly3y4lL/xmSVejj5JK7ZirpKisqy0pF5jMEtr5f6oNa1kLugMG5qdL6qT8EWdDk@5zCSRu9S7ukwJ@Wh60apexYzhbdpsR9RaaJbQbmvS4CbUrw05fsLEEqCDr/q922UrXc/My93KRcNIK4OV4NPnl8p5sVDIKNSF2Kk8GU@cKk7TkVa13L1@uk7rg2a0ZxpFdvEk0MulUi1leX7ZTReNcaVdaijFODPpZ67i18N@WWmpNSl8SfHJ@PgmTisNvjRlhEgtHSk8tc/5p@IsVlfHisk387esWamDsitGW1WtO5@sskNGXIQj@RujOuhrt9BbRysqNL2od/t1caQs5vWS2b4MTxrsuD2XxzGF03yRfLJa5dhBGE/CojeqMlHly4F506jMLnWaHq5iU0E7Fy4lqhzSBuliPVYKcefn3VyyxU6eykIocRWZpuehav3Kp0QFLVccTGQmO66PhGsJpgydWG1UYhoVqTW4nWZvkssGter2xKRS6szVy@x4nhvPRs3WIgzTq2a7bBiN@o3ZL85CvVJc7lWH/WaukL3msxxnxKtKNl8da9N2bzK/iESpUSF8M7qKl6RBbBwvCsvu5VRL1kqrYnZ4EfF1lVLC7HKm/FSVR0@Vnmn2nuJSu3FdojuZOK8wT8u4eTPs0AZ1kZjkzyNCfFUcsvGWMplNp/1qXVGLy9r1FbA5Hgo3z3t0Wutc18x2/0Lgby5aYOmXVKHYuClpjfObi/60r1ByGMQ3S@uX52WjcJMb37LzYn3Zk1jfuHo5r0bjUTHZ882ik8pwmotGO/FJqTIr5DQ9trgCrT@oLWtloV65otjJVTc/9pVElk3oV6v2LFJPCzex3tVcnEeiufRCGSYSLWZxXTrnrxM9rTiftErs4Jqe3ybHxoRrcfU0r4pVKvOkhZe5hZlnovnL2MXNtTCKzfv5aaiYnjc6xZiZrIidTuRpXp@PhUqBFZuL2TxUK1SvTSUSXbSvb8eX0ApRih8srvNx4Soi9BlpdZvVC2pPaXFphi7RoXmrfe1TB8pTRfCNa6FCWIvlmUWNg5nxbWZa6sd6rZHcOc9cJIdUP8LnfU0jVryNPd08XUn6zcgXn4DKSYj12fUVmCQ9s9WMLK7FZJddtbOJDtcrrNj8JZ2OXFxMk8VQqFROlruU0YhOQFqe5qGbUk4OXdfazcjUl6vkFv1h47ZVz86vErdddlLrNGYlPBkL08xcrI7qrWWlsGhJQiw/rufFDOUrXs@NalIT67l2XqdrfbEQGY0vzgvnwvSSny7yio8ZFFvL2dN0IiRKVzIn6Eqhbg7TfLibGIcXfFFLP122qeUFly@x2UQ7oY8lvjSqtIyRMetoopSOPEUXPrM@qkmX0Vy9eaOMWsNKReezV6G4IeTGjUnstjVa9GZCvl@iRDM54@XFeSVmKpllQbppXV2X@g1mydcSpUpBXzA9uvDUYGYm3Uo0as1Br6JL5REMnL5uS1UTMqgUc6heU5w2LDLzdvqynxgY2XMmUS4tqi2p4mOu8/VRLmTMdB89nFRDuZWaL4XFeXxQv76cMHp21h/6Lmtx@naUUecVKmr2wx3OGCfrItvttmktX18ZxlWi1fNdXsu0UA/dxjMXK7bZC2v96bCb6E7OZ0/d7tVTr924gOa88QmxxtUTNbi@vDDiYpJn@61MtpxWZxpT0id1MTIpq91WqCv6uotccf4UumQKo2KPrVSGq1WGL@kdJZGb9K6y3HLUSrSpcL7K9G/DglZq5Z66heF0xGfLCz58o14YvptIZTE91xPxGBtJzjgj3J5M2r5EWpZ88fBwOQxl8rNYju7r9Q6Vr/qyHVWFXlC/jXEV2oj0K7JptOLNRj5ZzxayF@XL/I1YTjaK3M2Nr3tdzObTzVjpcjiOXHZZI0NnroajRogalbPjPm2aianUkApG/lzPLYa34@vJtDePz8pGd6VcclNpMGFFTht3yko8lr5uP0WrTDh/RedvV7ISikcXSarPi/0SLdfHN52ElL@gu/IQJtA5kP/xzdVU50XdGCY7UPOrlRLPtqqDtn4hD2tAodybarw4SUrjoRC@pep0I1GId@RLka9265N4tyfdNEvhuDhdwPy1m1tdijkaWr3VbQynzE0sD6ZrJPJU7Awn17NK26hHc@1muRah2k/1nMgW8@Vy@9bss5UqMyjMzFY8cZFn@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@StffoIXTmv1uOPPGDfX1VENVXhh6rbQOQb3NvvnJBdy5wONOG07f40E3hT1bdjRCxP3GSnI76Owk@JuRc5JdWBM5eagB/drXclkFWQX3z6ZhqLnLxOxzX85hu8hcaJ7TuxXYHPlDbtyRJ/TH1D@IkfgePX6Y@P7U1heITl9ptvSJxkRVq0IMnw4OQTJ5VXtaWdWbJAHp26nG6hPPPgZ6te/9dAOlA9kMlH/EkuHcAsEIu9O@AIUJNHo16LKhwuC8r6OSjex8d7gnc5QR@cNGfHHwyP5Ybsu/NoIons0gOXU2SDkj0wkNfecYLE3kn4pTfiSnDmtpK@GU0nGnn@HLTotTmCvzf6qHGSvs4ZNKb4Y@EexGJmSA7RuAVw4Bnv@jbjTGG7aZy2wI5v5OUrXB@Mr0Y@GgME8xz@0jHoRvzyAcbXV0meb6wP2nqQqVqOlRYZdl5SDa/d1MA4vM22W3MfI@IHdwJR5JHoyVbqCFJxXd9InkDyhDOHbyQPMe6p8VayDsn4M7dvJEuQbL0TuT9dhXTrSf8bACb28gRxfTTVR5OTZI@1oQfeCuTZUtge5PM5jF2LALIaxmqP3fzI3hoFfbBaxxK2HfGC/knEygLAIu2xOw@@30gLScW7kHssudgq0@IJ@oy@WJjtHAksfiQlgdrF5XuPdvCjLQKg/4EqRa/TncKt1l5XdEd@gjDsDHBrA7PC6Icf3qPMFsRd@WMfHOmzWgj74W7V0OLWBo/1Fc5Nu1qZVnam/XnsrWO2tZvjI7Gph9MpQxsVYvWtTb8WJaUPZQDiD9vR2OXJiz5uYu6MB3S81h4bPlrd4st8DL2SHuwRRXqkH/U2Qf7rucphuYecHIzIvY2ywPuEcSev2GmsoQO70GcAvebmCznjd2TG7qU/tbJfV5sDoI90asKbE0vR8mAantkE7iGPs9p1WydYyA7dx1Y8/maotItMegOZtZ/eIyAwT4EGPLI5atwZEyXl/y/u2rvayJH93@lPIZqbYCdtY5PM3bm8JgYMeA9g1jbJcAiTGLsNPbHdXreN8c3w2efWr0pSd/sB7Ow9Z3fOhrYepaqSVCqVpKq8vEklOV/Y@ODxFXMp8hizyQirl/Dp/2FygXF6yR4jjFpaJKkFrJkrbukGv3Znp9wMeSLpFxN3JY@a135ZA45qfjzxqPuFVslNVVDWcdOWenxeDv01zvyIuy@l70SZ5bLCdLoZiS8Zgo9LGP3sIEuTsHGtUhwHCiwZnlmS2Anh4kUpvlr/1aSYa5cyt5dqYMBqK50PnAWgySBFOVnL0zrXbiw6tffFryOj3HixFobopTIqSGXfcpLiHNu5Q168k6nWdRRzJJmDl@zQMIcGs6BjdFtSg029fOsrulmYDH7SnL4Nw3bGKExaYWAIxkMHFfLEnZVVq0S9jJun5rTSq261lw@z7m5RyopO4nWFEqB86rEJJN7e8rTZwrRJ6DdBxMF1OR@rETVlXh/gsqJIH7U5m47SVgV6tbCSkfjwScaeK7Wc55U4JR7c/WYfF0PRHbK13naRbjsCZXZpox37t@Q@eFxgZRAfntq75Y/k1iXYCvLQiW2nm1uQ2S2Lzfa2i2bsgH/8c3VlfRwN12@C/rrfvyel@mbqrCq/L2HgNtV41Mn9jIvCpdrRJy1N@F42X0KkYUI9hdbyfX@SQRnSnOFF1M064pOOLy0WHXgf5nvjXf@@TVq/eGwZhNED/zulzUIhPx6MQs7RDbHvOvVH8EfsT7XAr4j0jkGjs81w4jIZvC@Q1KnclcwVRUEqwrNyNgHiCjVZ4LpfXBf9B0T1fdKrayfK@83WHZDA2PtDtlPUXTySH53IdD18rYEVeLxCn13xMjHgu6NogrWTaMq/iXz8LuJDUviKK8a93qc4fCEYOd0wHGCQ4yoo6m8TA4Txr@qNg3KtltcBdOTGOm65yz1mPBFkh3UcksFe48VtdbgLlE55BWIBW9rbiYGz/GUeoVnNJkyFCdgpvII/QqEgV@Rfc2TY8lkpzizh5076VwReFrRXjwHpUeBdXC2TqJYz1UzhBCtePcuNZqsFRxCnfi8kjPf9bpeQFl68itmBT3DEtP/Oth9doc1ri7zk5@byc6n8vOQLUnGpfOtuGBfaTBZyV3/E5R6VGxfz5traUUR05Yy9S@XDYQLvrafKRnnapAVx4V3blTIqbcZ2KiOXyPltQe9Lzkqqjh3gNv9K8vX43tA9b7FMlf2Ybh9/Hd1BPvtg0E8WZ0Zpvh90fxHzo81hCavgVkmqo7952Mmk1AYRLU5yJCZoEPO03d2JobwrGonDc8bd3f7o5rVJ6pfMLBoS/21uYi2YIwkucZvvmHEPvJJQO5y9kgDBMDHQlJm5u6byVFeeJsCi1Ipp1jGeQtMTnEibneI7uNb9B/4xkz2NnCm3ujjzlWD@IMTLS4s0g1jorriL2ZSWJqPh2JdETdQTq0jc9nQW4mIhcRZiB9q6g6SwbfryHqQTjvvtFSsnkoLCSIo5vtsczem4QNEM32VdiMxH58/1t85Rs0daYdd/UCXo1E32x@@kHtuM/GgU0RzwicChisaDQTfQft3UhJ9z6GBAGz/hMUIMMaE05J0KHohKeQ9f@nEMVcqrKiBP8M4wzojGt4itDUswwkSTaO0EBHKUd0r9KXsmZjdoG/LkxVdj@HGFAO7Sti@BhPSczB62PEBLyzvmYZGQ2pH53R@RCkSEh@zzEK5WNx3nH@Og9X3/SG0UCn8rFt4XEywzpupC/v0HVUmoSCZjo1AsFH4qfnCc/XAwlaeNmVYWsD7kANBTJ1joP9HY9O8Rxtkp0YrBBSNS/SN/eO@3845T89tsA74ZM0cwlMeRL16U2c8rUki3gr97Und7kado23UH8YK/WJ/Fd22LHWt4Dt4QDfxhLxjJS6PwPmiDgebdVCfsdsMJG6LxZEn4gUo9f0RMeZtVaZTYL63GhXUXdhdL3EBkB3bgdxPesx9pzQbSUwO43@cHQA6cKAJCsjEJVZ/AhNprdZtBD8NpAQLwshRzwCBApLXHLf9JHBxG4l/EQWnC2mFrDM@8TdMz6yT9Qp4rNN39YUDSN2Yw9wpXS@BOHdw4rtRVvXrY@FyqlRV9n9eqnyoH5QO1d6kax2W1Xz2/5ABg6rh6QtKlrkpnB5R61qhV9i4aVUpwS3Wq6XKGUzq7VOVfz2vlel1Va6pyen5SIWgEvlY6a1TKdU9VzvZPLmixPvIUQVBn1YY6qZxWGlSsUfW4VVPNieup6qE6Ldf2j@lnaa9yUmlccouHlcYZGjuk1krqvFRrVPYvTko1dX5RO6/WywqEOQeV@v5JqXJaPshT@9SmKn8qnzVU/bh0cjJDaPXzWbkG5FNU7pUJy9LeSZlbYjoPKrXyfgMExV/7xDxC8MRT9fPyfgUf5V/LRE6pdulpoPXyPy6oEGWqg9Jp6YiIczLPcIX6Zf@iVj4F0sSJ@sVevVFpXDTK6qhaPWBe18u1T5X9cn1LOSfVOjPsol72FIJ@ctMEg7hF@fS9d1GvMN8qZw1aMy7OG5XqWZY6@TMxhrAsUdUDZnD1TKglJlVrl4AKPnAHeOrzcZnSa@Apc6sELtSJa/uNZDFqkJjYSJKpzspHJ5Wj8tl@GdlVgPlcqZez1GGVOgoQTLT7uUSNXjDV6CfCSz5psDpm5HrcnapyqEoHnyrAXJemEVCv6NHCbNs/1jynubzuLDxye/IAb/6UT5tCnnYSv189KJPGJ5Fh3Dj9ghadn9OHd6k8WmhsJv3Up6C8Vn1t@zfj269BvxNia26ryQl2L7r1EEspi0CtX5wn4knrg3KusLr69eun0lfa59a/fs16L6mZQuO5GtoL61OlsprGbths8zY/ZVtKMmr3jfb17onj5aSt5Y01PmTV@nrb19XweBGAjZlIByUgYG1IRn7V2OyrRJN8xJy2FXHEjFljkTneDCP6p/9H/EPWhkQCCWe5t7C@jj0so4HIJ8riT41wUBAdGYTvAQQdbjIf@f7320wh2Ry2/NpAlTV1uOyItoG3mewz1W/825nqudn6jCzemrKyYtzBGzftGJgh/9IsU7pf8kOmLCOmPf6TNdhwQ6QUZqUpfsiqb59k3kh1@BcVW2F2y7oS53Agp6VfK5@xmStsfNiaST@26TK38OocsW1ovbvietf85/haCtAEC7D9IpYEUzlSXV9P1CGtjPVJWxi@6u9QaBK0aU3FUn3n87IOD/niLjhZnxbjYfCQxJ7E8FGtdLp3cXhIkhPYfvj5p7/995ajPe4PR7968vcS7SBKJnOXtOhJQGoaZyVmyT7pPYdzwXIS0X3QeyiIKJOm0zixSSqt9ZwpOoLE1xAzEMiNEGGgjyAbLoIEDF2F9/n@imPG68KZqQdAJkVqFtT0mg@s4TdJVeIx0BIvmd0p99oD/gFsO/3NFLcE6QGkh5jfG4ymNHJpc8Fyzz00Dgd4b8PPilEk75pxPGiaO0jCGMhM9sKAN/j8S4/tRC@SXouOxnzlbueahMTKLBYmSAuHXKImzsPIzGBJDCjlVz3e6PNSBwdCFkI9lEZ1YuOhrZkzwXvE5qwnhoZ8vbtDXfTmjW1pW8GQmtVIif0/HTomORsYFbnQoGYAm5tHls82h43QH9ey6oeMVHj1BpwtPWL1bxq5i8jRULaMS3T920SQUQIrDijDSRPbhmOKXJoilp0pNv1b/GD4/0GeLIC/TRtOgh5zi@Vw0B/7L@QkQxVe0e6VmRJMzI2xxDW1mJvJpMsYzGOyY@4sYfoa3oMcLBELdO9MTcKlhBTLLGAABjnsGsn5Cwe@PInvmrRz@shz95Wc9A/7rd4gYwJymaViDu61xzqXZ67I4UdWjvALKtHcCeKrfGQ/jywzsOEiKXYzVa8jV2C8K7LMAdHrb9noYWc5D02woWhmeDycCnpqmcn/oG8YxatM2@Q@kiq6PNiXPQ5BTKGUwDcnIEaA8N2nJMGabdTmLhBdSDc8vbCVX@lVHBEuSQTyuqwa7J4janZ4z4ylSPvSgNMONAk4r9s6ZtONP5pguegKdPYhEkNTmdfsxgSNaFukVSOM8M3mieu8yE4s9mymxHi12F/0v/cRYNkXE5cpkU9FgEq6YM2r0yYHg@q@jG43bvwd2Lqbbr/SZ78qLTmvhGmOd@7UCnb6r6OYI6RxTqBd0joUc6nZ@o5E14zRYJILHugPt5XTlJuYRrRn4Ih1i5T@x6UbAoyVmTuwyv3St0akTVnIdl4b9QVfMnft1yW@tJ15h4gi5CgFF2a1GgSUoTfhkub8bGP8Um51cPl0kzSnySR/0xz3mv1Osxd0p3zr9Pfwrr8e9cfRID@YOq7rpq2BcAQOFymE@8hXn4N@O5xEao@mAwxJ9bOL@nna8JewfO2L5Uupv1Mbao9bdubAd@AzKQo7I@oaf0tNdbTyYWzuYTuhtrSwWWuKBDimGvIAonZ7VjM@OrtQR37fH5I@eM53LtVJ0PL7JD5ImeJbmNGdSBoUP0Trdd26OoTuwpadLeUHbNSxtj1HN6CheRhaGZqKhPBQh1WEbX5KQz1hE8zPExzT1TZGpbtwoL0BwWgKZVNMnJ1x13MQu/FzpXGMzbhszNk2Q8uasfXBliiqU0@MtUTMsNkfTYkpzqzxhtB@znaTV@wMiCA6y9nJm7oeArS3YfbrRkQqQs1rKcArCE1VP7hHsDg2w72kj/ierTabxXzb0v4VPQlfZ0RHqvecuPc8xAzNe@qn/1ENH2NXnXebLdphqfoY1d@/Jz1wL4xGKHpaUqqwUSwWc8X3MNFe1Et5ngj4v4kg5jiV0/NqrUGM1C7yzcCwayaYz0G75DYWsSOH0F1E/TcIZFOeJObGN2YeVHDjx9fdkhMLd9Olvm81Ye4lCqO0OswmWZjkwyEHDoM3KBpCqelIrcLpAUL0sZBESwnoHocu08HHZGmxeLI3P67wDbh1aVx1cR76jStzGgkA/4HTqNaQdwZt7fae@qTn9yz2wcis7k0p4MzGPLMME1sqDY41bw1aEnEvm4TT9nFHIkL0gF503xqSbGne05DDFRbjEovGDMumrKWmeRN0A5oDhFfrLsSCI@LKdASbIJIR0RzucRtrBwsS47IgWgHNrnbYs0UFK8exzuB0@iCatkK1ekvbbOy0ooHvtzlSwnggoQCQn6dZ3qWVQ9zEbcYxApzVAt@bHJKwQUgWkn3jLnzHwtffjfS5Y6ihUWXcCzbusK0XQERRfcSTFBHbMgt22J7COW@Wu71JAwJ1s2DEEkd/BGLg4VCKsKL@5gHBXzxcPLij6nJ/z/oBREUORhQN0hmAJae6fjrDgAft@nOugAzSHYvAjItBg4z4yZLvlA0s/QP04t4pnKZlhEYibpq1zDwMEEJTbAOhug3xLwrnDcfkjNDnM8I5x4UPcMlL8GZLFudLUikbQCRRcmMBzNxCmO8Xw8xpmPqwstK/Z4dtqMXDQqgQb9AhyUcwIib/KDSil93KdUM5YLLU33bDG8RtIklBreHP1Is7NpnMO7AUo5O54kQwHW9q25CkUddvm4zuorZpfvi7attYLHa/9KWjdMaOzCX2WaZ47eLpxJ/4R88o/nRTwaugdcxErwJ6kkqyG2BdDVKnuJsqnpm4iZMsr1tOV@mlqhRnqmjk0lVuUlU2nNhT6UzvogZEP/6mKTN6Cd9K4h5QO7aDCk6v@SC7mwI7oGMzDUJGpjzibVzrAYKCVy1lfdqh@LUTu2hOHdtLG@YnX8HjG9/uf7kc8qqQjnfwYK7usRjgUqn8KbsB72c0QVnNBv5h3T9nDTKarm2u0k9IKkuwZDgpsod4q5VJtpLdVKuDppwaolSEhS3Z9BXzAKf0Lv33VmV0A7kkslIIbnW1KCTGs@vlK9rKSrcYOVhw4pWZfyUEHPWgI/Kbr4zJMpDJpOaVkdwWpnzOyW4ChXQBxy054v8zIr1OUrGiJERDHQofwphqJc9/oO0ZnzEzCF5/rMVaJ4pPYys9NPJXccvXZtVIU7G09OxSsqhMYlWxXHiqsGG25dPSwstXG2YdbAiQd1I8wboTGIk168wSvBYJy1hLCUbs7DRsBSKh0mxLCF2p6y0QwOkuN8h5M1Q5CVfmmsLZZcRJrZypQZJJ/EKYdvVaAtkJoKyTqgX@L@twXHdMTuyl5YpSTnf7shFhYZl@f2pY2MKm358aFlI40e1PDwsTy9CyluvPjotUTwgLcClR7xjYppSUQSbjIVnqYaYUIzS9Tvoy97uZBdgmpKq2dTpzqpJlkQ5dkm6D/zxIx6xqR6Op4UjMu7K9cR1TS2tc67vfth6ZNfV2i7TrppcE6c3ZQAQg2rTAfXSdRchsW4EkthjB9J65J3c32aP9mmxYeA@KqF23d@nXvSmwZlUpZOcVSuO9P0Z@eyHyufkoCvEWa3M@Pry9XaaxxoWncNhGaddZcOLrPIPVuwRWaeoSPZRm8RJIuRdByr0A0noCkp7Y72m95M/VIeLU@c@B@PJlHgb/@Y02UhoGSdp2ACM29sGT5vQ5mCukbK3ynbqm3CqzFWI9@TkYv8zC4Ligd/Y0TifeNWF1@19/GM5G5VjK2fRYWYCRxWp1Hi0PaLHU5v2uLmdUJd7b5r/f3AV2J7D6fE@LH2NdGVeJ7@wh0Graq74FFs//4hL@eYluTc8HQTxlhiFt2fkXp0MejBALkzwVsxUSgiy9D9UZaUY8nTsr/Hi3Ouv9GAFPl1bLPkvJRzH4JIxORSJNJFZqxJktXCyczGpl5Nui7dmz7a8ubH8QDkjH6SxEgMv3YMcXo9SMSI9V05mt9YvWsoXr2TxdSb1tJjbJyyf5mznSN4h0PEynSd33J3r1fwqypsX0wF/Q5K/MGFmC5OuFSOKgvamNW6o/7t34Q@clU11q5PFH9kjLR67jrK6qUou2zNozPqxiLQ7f5@smoQZjIERqPMB5TSSXOzG5YSPzZQDPlm2Hkz6Xzrtogm20Pb/Z167y9YJ5O8T5hS3rIXwnHndxC0G/RYyO/IT585vEpG77Ogc3kp9g69bivseoRpsaCy9uSaMlumZmmt7TSuoSBcdqNVxqc1ZRMWMHh6FvRTPX@hIp5tnFJrCXaE9PKUQ0iJc1qTe8M6CfHqOby5k5HlhW2q55ASsXqVvWyv0CdWv6UnXrP8DJ2Q51Et9ae9AL7OazQm12k@/8ub5uAzP2Frhu@dQ4PEw5PLmZml1Bzx/@VCgU4ATnphnxqUXKGw5OiYNwPV16HTbx9cHk78NPN@uoikMLRCbYNIeZfhR2SdRE@XB4K9EogAMVRWkcTWCc4GhiTOtNItwD7Dl9vMr5PZKS4oGnrfgaZ2Avt39q8OBjkGCev6m@gUDQ9011xn0xok@asmXQUMx9M6oNNfTeNdfkiD1I6MCjjr2SxsB436xfLeDgY2f3h/OKz8DluSCHi8/@iJ8husd@txt66nM47LZXXHkdmq5weJisUJAiuEookyfi8MWe8u@DbiKEM4oAt7Dr57vhLYPDCbh@tshvmYb@ACdpGaxjNf@2/DDIuFe/uTQwieR3IPOdcq/xvOfWpSXK5SP058FKwAxC@0Wle81BpsV8mi1Ma6B@SxV/EUbvi56qy@1g2FP2iWRc5sikimTFL4zw7PnSYOpidPO/h0E/Q6Qj28FzOX76zd3LlCwpbpnrfnkodsDDgsDQOCFEz8tqPG7B6dRf/x@s27Ac4HEj23jtk9iEv7EkHcYYj5ml7kedDk0vscTvGldjBhyLylyRbymANbpjh/4/Easgs9aJ1iTACq7a1Kf9VgqRq41rT62NR52f1wjCv0WjY2agnn7ET@f/AA)

[CSL interp](https://github.com/jammy-dodgers/CSL) waits for key press at the end of the program. If it doesn't it exited because of error (stack underflow, see `StackHas()`).
I used Chance's chat suggestion to remove `!` from the first line: `50;'51;` (hexagony).
Second `'` for Shove, pluses for boolfuck. The pluses are compensated with
minuses on the first line for brainfuck, on lines 3/5 for Minimal-2D.
Space in `v e` for Beatnik. Insignificant refactorings on line 2.

CSL code (line 29):

```
... v e
      .
      .
      .
      >
      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!
```

Redirection operators don't act immediately, `e` should be used to invoke them. `E` executes instructions in reverse order because they are popped from stack.
Additional `e`/`E`/`!` should be avoided on CSL path. CSL code has `$`, so it needs to be after SNUSP. Solution w/o `$` exists, but puts
more constraints on line 1.

`*` was removed from the first line (no need because of second `'`) and `e`
added, so fixed Paintfuck by removing `*` after first `e` and adding 8`e` (==`w`).

Almost entire polyglot is in parens now for Underload: `(` before `coding` closes after Paintfuck.
Removed Underload parens from lines 2 (at the end), 15, 32, 154, 156 (the first one).
Incident line parens are left to get rid of Prelude "Error in the program: extraneous closing bracket;".
Grass line parens are left for Brain-Flak Classic.

Changed incident prolog jumper to `+?`, `?5` and `?6` didn't work.

Klein 201/100 were moved to line 28 with insignificant changes to fix 99.
Cubically: jump over `/` with `!` in Klein 201.

Other langs as usual.

Answer (score 4):

## 191. PHP (`-r`), 9400 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bcyPNkhj2TMj/wC81DX4DgLg2QIAAQWAGvA05wyE5vAxnPpIfpgE0gCYb3T3dDRIYDr84sh1rrVYP0mqtWGktnbMrO7wPivCGww9WaCMcYb0qNvQbvn1ybDji/IPjzKzqCy7kzHznHFmOEEig65KVVZWVlZWVdemW4vR/85softihqY97uukyV3Vc1rG1G9XOsPUxe65oTjFfiEQQqmH3hgPVcJ3VSJTJjGlGW@uAn7nmtWpon1QbwvOMWbbZs5UBc/uKy1SnrViqw8yhaw1dZnbnJyswtjUwr7Q0phxoRg/AXNW2bNWl@GXGTg1dGbQ6ylRMcSpDy4Z4h22q@ufBZ5e1zcFAMToOQJYYe23ajorwbdVxTEy@wthoS21PIS0DqGJr5l5j/8VUVIWxF1BExdLVEVNajmsrbVczDaRJjh3vnx4fTqWQZfb2ZHt7OjTPXqVNg20P29fTUQV2ajuKrkzjX2aNoWvuutPhRdboqYbC8plKJj8dWWLrtjKTZIXZqtLparqagQZhadZXdUu1GYawrmmzXSiSXs6Vc81GkDLTxrTlIHIabYXphYI7VZ98Dghv2n3VgBLmpiNlP3IqIu9HdDTKQLHHLO70TRv4yGZDR@2wW9PuAHMZ@jiRgvRs9Im1FEctLSOCgo/g2jBvDWAi14SmbY1dlRmmkabECLjM5L3mNGPlixjaONidDi@x/N502AowWvu6O9uW@TI7Mq3xdGiFvdb25rFzIcc7wobZgdaYipPZoQJBlE2Y8NQ9D22zM2xj13H7KqTE7oat6UTa0Px1ZolOnkEHi1L7czBAfWwO1HBuDjNUIK9jqW2tq7U5W6gjVzUcyNDJMA2KcKvpOuuoOiQIsLdTzDGxcYKglq70M@1MBNkKc2GDa51prG1ZjEcxXYMibefKTMW6s08Qr/cdNrIGzNEGEO22zW5XVdkn1epD8kjHjDD4tK2pavm@RRVgDNUjjWpBd0bSmNj7gU4ehW5txQK@dwQNXG0AwkpzYw5TFUdDcQhJHNXoEFUtX1CaTJlgWHajQXeFqg9twu2oNnUYwgudy1YBpeKLqvitrbku8TxrsENVsdmJraqJSaE5kSVkZmIOLlYkQ426thbbOtiOQePyFBnFgsa0CydvXkYUlqmxxWYVvjVJqka29jfZ3eIFurmMBAaw7LiSYLUfmZO9uFDhO5Jb2Z59HwGsEaCKzrKm5WaVtAUFTLtQwKyCTnSlb/IZSw9lzNam2iLEchyqA60BooO9TVHN2kPbxnEgIKpyDZXWTaMH9ITK2kMD6WGwUg6aoG2CGE8x9QaoBnKT2gh6NVL4pK9BoznYJKFuwUczIiiMZ8DGgqJevo6pDwkOUjou8jJQBZIixt0ue8u6iqZjEohHVLzUtuoMdRfTDI0OtjyMVmonw7xitKHjAtDAvIHsFEBKAcD6g1C/pEIBMDSESVXFqJ/@8Z91ej3A02i3QTIJdn3LOmabxl2FCguDGUOGBXGoU7EALoW58@SQwY2iax3FxeyNsciCCkG53ppDvcNMyNC@1aCX9pUb6NnQudquypmcD9UpNlCuuTTROOdCxQdKCxqWMqC8qdpp9nwDWqmtRqLEM@nB0O2WWdraYjEn@0P82Wr82ZMLFQqXyCSWFrPZXhUYLrNEQeCLPcY5bxsTA4zjKo6pdSLW2O2bRp6l20xq10xLNeKxCRyxVMxuxRIZlHLxRFWrtTNdzejEY2vAi3XIOJaotmvtc231sjqVPJwloLlFNNhd1Xg7IUVA5FCnuMkOQBZnQLS/TQtXKM50mkhyjM6EgpEw02E3PCBKqgrypYkMAnIo4@iqasVzGTmBYgLh5tYbI@bVdAqHqPCqdpmMRWPJcNUJA9R0oqLYWU80E8WWbvVxyAGiGI4FI4GNvNuGcRYlo6O5oC@mWIv4mkYRkCwkE2/VmK3igOzzEXVJ3uUwfRoFpcAQdKHJnqx2Qh0ZhAD0ZdeZkca6eQsZUplwmAHRYWCmSg@aBhLzijR4RXhOFDJZJa4mALaWysrplgadALsbyHTB86G6AXghz2EAG@8kIdkzUMaApc2H1aDDMK0LfWkA4gF0mbaKMgeEj8oHFMxkSP3PAQ0ZdeVcOl8sTvaxmS7m2tlG@nsQ0p@yj/YkrHxjQmmAkaer3jJdMXpDpadyPYop7bZquUJQQU0cF0TR9HhDgWkxeGacfmTx@XTeNIh4qkWQBwp53npiKFRQugg1Pa2DMGWKmGiA3meDWNLH07kDwM1U5tIHBJkowAfpgSJ4GgAwmTpS20MXpBow8G1fa/eBZ7F0BpeLfBCazh6CwrmDZE93/ayxMHL9aT6SyfpBWIwHUaSxRWfxwOCKqOoTAdT44YDHMSvOYA5i0y8iDASh0ExWyQDvfQHnwDTMOUiBkD5aBJmM4e0AmtgxKpQwcHlqF3VWX8v0mwjaDNX4DvJf33UtZxXGCc3tD1sZ4JTsiT3edQ8MZJasa4811@Tulm62QCw70D@zXg7Z9rCljaYqRGF@G145kRtQwLoOq8HI/XEIXBePdR0QmBS@gcChKIkEN6HgvxIAElAGCBXvOiSKt0GoHI@NdlzKUFfKQKeTUkzCjivBZEXCVD5dNswBSiF2RooBanowadMM1PSFzCeRr8wd6nzZT3pdLJa5MjUjfhd78uRJbDVWB8n@5MkzcK2h6xm6kuB6Rq40uRAugy5KkSIXxp5TCgy7jN2fe5hHiUtsthGOSp80K66cr64WLlPKuSyeeXwmQNSBZAPoND4ATyxRq6EzkZDqt1DRTKs7WfsNlM7HbVuzBBFeKjcK9wsqFIgM2sDCSaCtVnGQfZwmg5oNoyAore1@3I5dnOcuLi/uLjrJi/tYClMnqkqtBZWC/OKDTM82hzBcJs6XV9PyZSJxXoBBslWL5WJL8Xg5rUNGSiLxXTmRVDi14zEVpHb84iIGRBX0OW/3bcI3SuUTCZ9UUA4cmEEnjMcyd2XIv5W4TCRjkDYRS8EUoxaLAWXaSASHKo2cOUGgg6NXnDAbyWSE2NC0r/E7I/YhLAMTLJ58G/h343hy0jq4BunK2o6Oqkja5toIeLNLPLBDD1/jWmW7pLEaMNxCDWC07fgzI5xLG0PSn0m5NcMZ0XQQISgMxx6Uq9oEDCLuaiOYIEC/H3uKEI7fqAttwITT1NXMGakmEoOOw7C7Z@ZqQ4d8WMm0nYAHQO8Bp6UrbejYk@guJHYBCIHPs9n5MYnqDOJpVYlmNV@qIwwsbcVA@nU00tqHmtNH8oJmhVMJuwtURZUddAOVqLbL2jDm94DS6khzuQ4PfHSMSXYUJ55ArbHBtS5U9lBjwEJ5NgAazs02zHdU0Bwwlk8e2ZZxo9mmgUTObAFqYPgqtsEU8nnkBTZqNHbzmw/Tdx5yoNhMsByibRjrNHHbTptlDVM3eyZbAgBkzUyGM/au0YYigM7nwvSSOdonIlCjZxrjKR5Ucbh3UEeUSwVf@1YQMkvwmSuQNWx@pQOAB@p8vPv9FowQcjGXg/J7vhx9/EqGsEzXEQPbLAAQBlcd@QZb8nvV6o8nzEHIH3wWCfxkqrxj8nm9AgMqlEr08E@UNNzJeQj0cy@q47nm1X2LNCQ0ZYRnGRO1B2UQ@qmoDu82UMPoVDCGeqSYQDrT4EH7boPsPOkP1Yja7ptMugANI19n2Y56k0WBI4Gg64OqnIasVJuUMT@ZMABHXHMIWl1H1bWB5u6SuUs3UHUJhmUvFm1uAYJDTXUjYr4RiFc0SQWy1uhx@K0RDkhORKUn2z/Y3GoeNk52alJ26NhZXWsBB3fU5gAUT111JDb9ibIjFZCJ9J@u9SPTdGu8ua519sVPFNN4yfc2m3u760eNo/e8EITG0QZDXcGirC5OAWDyY4r2elXIDti1zYGvkTuiIRYLSHp1wmKP01MRu4yxQ2GvD4WXMHyANvhMO9Jrt1na5F4/UACuICDa5WkM6yWTCEl2ej9QQJYJJdrqM3bLC6xgoG@ln7BfB@jmxT@cSGC@k3P3iNwxho4VqtmdLFP4jdvt4qjtB@cp@DqNrK4HwQUK5lb@Sfu6IMtM1FxgH98y4eOrA3PxzUTNBfbxFTk@XFWYj24qZh6oj6xEyHAVYi6uqYg5gD6mFcIUXrkI4soU99CyhchrbvSDiXzcFcKNSxsBKlroEEEeYJ5zx4AvOzhNtJEGPJKXJ2Ixii9WsHQHJidrCIL88hmXMSAItDjH6mTckRugKIRRpEHn4IsYfjxnBFlvKk3olUFpvZBQFEvrIMDkUpC46Cc2p5KaWhDsg/N2zetNEAHDUJf2QsJRfiLehN5qSbhT5HkL2qY1DvXluzwn/kAT4iTUuwqc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vxYSUaS7gTmBI3TNBEdrTHFqTDEu8iK@wX0Qkb9YxoV5LQUw@sP6x9M18s6UURkSyGMTltYmT3cDVzGXkImLxUQyu9dmUXdAZ6WcCdKZQszF8DBi0uvQzB2BVWMRguMMlHqTKS7Tqo9HOBA1evSUwmtsTMqCWZijZI3rgLH9eeSbtFROFaandISi3WZh8ofsLYOlKmSC7rZb2ECjQBYvuPeeA2cPWPLJBL@zPmLTYBOHdoe3qakc8/8MvOtAAs83TV8ak0PuOJtCNeKP7YGuJpOihn/ktSzBXQ11TiAzk@hLKtoKrCIruO@ajRs2EpdN9xR6g3iwaF5gTf6DXPMJnvOS2qg87qvecnwmReNJwxlMb2oBqBE@c@NE094HkU2Y/np6mTrqpdAgLn@BoatDavF3UEVf1Qxo0yJivKKdnnWPBcpjbH7pD/osrYF9qV83C73yqrE4yWa6otGQ1azpKS1Mf4QNbuR52zLR13aNKY9FKD3E770RoTEp3deWaO5vonE8AXkVb6/VU23s@BHbbB52dJhvZW3o8wiqexsRIB1Yew2nr/PchEG8Hie94mE6aTj/fwpDEIm3oNUhaXOZOh8ikTRFWV1pjnHT1v52zMENSRUHw1NrJZK6AY6e/phEsqFvWw@lxwKX0lcr81HyBnZNk3lQkyxfW09zgRHUWS@1f6PUwcmkDRU/nOyHng0LcM2YGrjmgNANPt3XFAWZyRXOoN9B89PMYg@Ng1Ea2ClyPsHdQHG9p66FVkiCNBRqGrjkW73HC85A0nbYvB2hwpwP9BEnRN0vfDim5Tj/tu@YLBLPt4krFA/z2FQKOLxLgMkyIgTLmQ7Rrm7f4fVDF6Js3Kv@dP@h9mluqrxBVaZ04Q2vPSd5pf4ldca2bfuZT8Xpuqdy2PjdcWOQn1fyvZWhH000H5tv4@xghQHN2HP47n5XDNNMUI02G47B7fjJRKItlhKHsgZZU9J6pl8q9rAI/Dzb30O6i@BfPrxV7vtiS5S@LLU87Mg1ZPB@U99dZ@/pLnEDWZRtXoULORwbbebJLrF48XEGYQ@DS8vzKbefKlDKT5caPhxrAbvdvlbH3/BlDykPU9YYUa0y6NSh/mKBSBodrc3375@S2/Hhuna8TSDNoV75UiVDjXusqiGf6nWlSls/J35hCzuW@Xjx19aE6VOdqeQetKxW3BnIzLe5IUHSdL2@e7B58Y6FyohqLwkyYBeKhkdCH@iRmjl9Vahy80feogFF0DTr5F1WcufLOAoXcwsn2ITgO0TGbsGcMrYnGDdHuaGgcPU65vuX1bLMzUUiM@VaJVP6yIjWhszsqfR/S77cGJsyPzQEoDMZXtL9AShYN/juBmEICNWPC8DE3e3@pGhRaUDygRbVrJ402768TOvmHJvUEXKnAtM1Q3TH@PkTpeUK0ZZr6t7QMyNKORluA9TRuG/1SC80oOWLXAgvMFw6aQlrdhwwXfJwRM0ygHs6m3Ufmz2Ez0yNTwhmT@SOjVciA/qVJJozUZBly7Lbnfoghj7BTy5lyZuVRduQ6qNlSdYU/RqXlx/BVMoVH8flah1BuacEFF2n4skywrhWdEj3WGIildWCC0lcHKnkf0eyVztXQ8R4PAo1M/M6JzmRpkeGBdJYGfd3A34kloJA25JoGTKlcxe6pOCfRcW1ShD4kX721i7nE3R0oPZWfEHhMdASmCdzOxmdygXO@kWKV7zBpQzK@AP84K0DHuVbHjveci/D1uA3tORw8im1eH2@jBfSLnTqTnbtk8wV1z@ibfaOv9m3qHL7voe4BHOnysx2PVQLK31eca9y/R/IomMv1nTB1dVPXv4a6KA@5dDTN@cbZLdx734Gk34R3rLQgQjy@aMeDIZuIRGP3Q32nrw5hZHJM17TUNPkeAtXR4sN/59ubdw9iDjvTVLvDNx@g@U9xtZauslsNinDlhFe851uTWrqp4BbRR5R3oIz3/Br7VNu0v2j86Cmma1n0aFr60KEfsvOmu/MNmKtsm0r6NcyguXzfB2dZtWe22n3tS0VqqYpraNdZz5DDvY/OS4UwppprLL2JwRldA1rZ4wwyQS0cf4yP3YfGv9DyzNzabwxte/xlwTC5mu/bW/kqAToeyl8svM6JpiEfNzZ5G3geWaoQ67QPchMp0Kgsp9UcaCXyg/afiT1cQnrRguEDSs9UvakwoTWyb7FfioV@suRpoc0KED7PePGQINwR8g1mhfGdYc9JfJlx@x3QqfBnLsJGDw878dUkRzdvQ9Zm6PqKIR5zR2V/RfGxhZHioysj88icyYq1zbQ6fNDepWuWw39ZupufW7zZxfpZqPH82a9oso7a5b9f0vQGpo0b20GlSLdt1WmjGRylMZeSXAQZZg@kclpnAbAHO7f4s3sD5ukqkyNe@t2@2lNwo9uehnvedGd2EATM09sEvgbxm6HiaG@GpqvOxTm9XeBrUL5Welp7Z6IFPIQedcWuKP6Y6BQYNNsQt33Nof3FnmN@R@IsRivvs5HTlnb/nNvjhpGQniS2ebL0LvO2g/oOtPVjvDI3r0ktVCy6Pyj4NJcMqOI5t57zt1Y8ZlW4HQ6soSMe83Mf4GmBsB15cE3hzq0GUjH9EYQw6yu6O9/WHDKmgn4lRsbA@ZDW/b2mmz32fTnHQB0DgYdK@AOMtQ7j9KHiQg8wnHlaIM2O8pkiHnv90tg3vbyJ1os0qT1818IRHYfzD044KbHfD8I0W5zacjLe0cgo7Y2kYxTetnoWxcMdQxweXNPOMIKLx5VkMpGI8ERoYO8ZAOZB0eE0PLjCz705TNccl2C1Ljs/Z4t3o9XcqnzPakxaldjlJceKHzpGsTWy6GTZEU9@vqhc1hZj6XRsMXZhrLJczAdXdWCsueDKBGxXowcvb0ACZih8Byy6vRpX@cEcp0@H3kCp6oBydmqQzQQVPX68hJ9dOsGV/X//lx1xFhBmcA5oNSDYgSB4FNYcqH3z9hnPV@TesCwFzxIiDpADOj/Zkt5oMGBQ0OL4EUDzlp1un5TFwSJx7hY8h3yU90vBGxftCLgt2OWNx0vjb/EUGfupvEq1TX04MEBv7rh9J8OONdrxO7SDrXvgQjDDtXHy0EmxXdZRcf2UNnLTfFk3zWs6kYEl@fd/yY9T0XZusc3Wy56OUYZyxF3bMp1harfNIZTaQ/JJtU0BEkcig1QYoiUKmF/l4Qnc5EznvIAj094pJ8qGH3XaaByz9BaL4ZFiPDxR1brxxcbRi7fnucvaj2yQVf/DL7KJO0E46bt0peRIKeaBVO@RscLRRYgOYmNMWhxJPEN/r7sm9rrf8vYAEimcyXC7u8djpmmJXkMnVelgps@N4r6DOLqpnb3jTgM65EoMq97ScSfaY2qgtMTTo4YDHQy8CULNe11tMT7kBpP0scuKkCEeGVPAxY/F0u5vPLqDSRZH7DPrI5Ol27gjGXyckDqeFhvU1r0NNYXwtqfsptoa0lr/TT6TL9SoOovN2lqdXLbaMfHU5vkPF6N8Ln0xWtm6zDoeUS8uRt/l8u@A6ibM5RafZrHnbe1v3i1m6rnPnx1lzCTpPlblW7NATCzeHe4ebh2fNE5Oj6EV7j3xs23aAyWQNchFtMe4b@p0HhboYmuq8w3yx/cBeDzOFhW2hvc0JBKR8PZZAhW0ltLSIneGRNNE6i8kn5feUUPxswBCpnU15nHULgwT2IbAbEg1rPzQwlO9TKQVJxOJyzSU8diBfMLgBrg5spRIJbEaECsNxPpKUrGHK/uMh30Nxb6I5XGyPZsLghTz8zv343kV55Lg/ndSbwsGyt@@3hzL4/UmmEfqDaB@qJdmu7G7d3q0NZkMeIyeJHVrlaLYN86FM/Y0bmvxjmLSERuREI1NNYlJlIB7xWBGl3C0VPdWhWoJ4dge8MTEoVR@KRIwJlCmhjeZXFY5LeJxKgHqIFWs1tS29q42ChXRG6ND6O54FX0hsC35qL2CZySBOUr3UmTw41UDsQpyeV3vkIS4kNcxJ6z@pLweh1XDMRr0Vkr1wFDljzoOg//QqOS58pdsxMRwJl@yNMvDV1dhztb3YRNVPkaxRU4IaZGXXfLLi3ciQJk6VwrN8Wgrlti5D6O0rlh4AFtA78O8apV9HJp0TMgTJr5@cYszCIVf/0FN21awNnT8yHDxMLU3bhG@3e3jGmpnXDUj@R7muaGBAxUAhS7j2BrB5ACYrUuynh/r5yQ3xQlyb6gkI6AjToz6WoLDbjSHjITYCF3UcXSQlFgbUXG8x4YOiLGG7oBO0oHhm9/6QspJhrYI833CaYNJUeDJjK8yppgUQVinNnuiGIbS2zYMqx944kWCI8xOCGds7Uk6DZTraQZzDA3UeXcVbZlkfVhlrj3EFfd6bCaJV4RVcqX77kAPAc65W@FCzf70j/@M36dw4YL7D4V7lFsH3x8JXxfc/8iLkWXw/RPflwffH3PfD1lsstlD5DPlxH4uKsbL57cgtt7b3UPmkBEV22egjEKkR6mBfKQZQANtAA19Q@2G4DyHoFkCPPHzt9DswCvQ5qiyoJZC@an2ZRyPB69ms6jR48wuQ9tu1RG3oNJp4Y9DvCUDFKtsqVhalrNQyPSNh5CO7PVwnydHmEisgpyL3GhW7UOrjbvymeS0FV2tlaq8vbOLyg8F6YNf0EWAjXDl/5xBGtzI76eAuLpIFl9UknICk@LgFJNjKKc6Jmcf0PDi5ACQBAYb3pknUCFNQSrgTUMduaQFjb1JTQvvMkJLj8rvSvEQpQERx413OUx3sWDnJm50D3W6TLgZpDMEO0awVWkeA57/wC7cC@NS3OnBgJl@NYcdDXD/wzkXfXDOwkOMszdMxKfvh8DasOfHhok7fLehtCyez@YLWbmUCHGoJFBBebH7fgaU0GFBALRV7cq0nMbG1u7Lg8PjmZsSCDI2DRZjsfpa8iKdSZ1f@o6YX@5Joq5vZ49fr297pAyXKlj/RohgEXy6mPNymy7pA7mf8S2zs3lTxExGcu5rEdOKU3qb9ojMYg9isyHADb5VbybXeOLu/vxyrX5hRGey/zzv9phoZgmZC1wXDt0dE5suJhZx19sIfIJ3yjkZ7xBIXgruRvKPp3B/EPzwXQf@DXXBhQfeluMIHUX0TyJGMg9sRoa6Z7I8KzrtzwvmlRdkjVdUGYsaZNiOzOxhCJeGibrMXqYnztr4RDrgdiHvKjSHQzoknLnliG4d8Wnmw514GLHrB1cQiLP3fSidrrUit@KYqHdSyT8imnEsXXPjiYghIKbPLM1COo@e5PfBlNr5iPmHdBzUA0cZuv8lThfl3F5G@EUIzLuvIElXHhwOgW6HpsUCy9im6rmOQE9im0PIoo2TrJfDAcB16XGk4mihguaUhsRAz5hXlHM85C8okRl0ivFRItNXRx2tByNOPJEC0fSdLAeXJSh42h90pda8GqCpyeorUAdsmsIa3jUwSqxVyBtUkNsQ2e38YOMyAsgwaSuxyq0RsVPDu9cGG36VxVI@ZVqJVCzD@OxIXFlD67BkXMqwjT7uWiNzRrerkRoWPoLMB/OuZg8yWCsYZjgLvcA9q2Gu@aZ7K0KUUc6VjGZ01FEcjwivXiKdIDx2e3YTS0gzLE6XZ4irEjrTt2h4slBxhVAKbqCYkneVii/nJkVDpZLpOxE87gUTDcjx2LX3wAkqQrw7UCwWH9I1JA7LMPLGL@JGynHtBEvXcbi@ZQZLJslOAQ@KgHkIgnbJpdF57zje2hXP1qCRMNQxOvj4pFnsXM5kLsFNmSTYItooN0CbQuteIgLzTkiySmhBv4C/VSwRvyExI25KXKRsI3QTAEDNjSY51euTfAFaUK1Z/Wlw7DokYDhVK5VV0RqT0r7CgC/W5ghEQDtHint6P9BXHNgBqqGMBqgNW@1oIC@fv1INQwUCAc8M8EJIZQhMZidS3l2lqeA2Msohyou4I04AQUEnbynbit3pJqhri9kqmbuq96DWfLhAvaYrNJtx9r/OZrLVu/iiXhtnQddM1OOL/ZqcLCwlk4vGUnzRQG3r6VO0kt0vgjLXzMCkcwRA6UU9UQV@BuWvtmhUF5W1@GKnll@iFOCFae8dJPjRyWbuFpX77OJTUJZSEGJzoRNfdOgCkVwmI99D@bCHLGZTwDN3eBMG3UCK2S9qySSWIbPYxAL8mL04TtKweXGcJYNcVej32d5AdLcpVcxviZmbUzkBRfCqP2AVccASG7maHnBwR1lhXtwD6h/P@BVud2W0Sq864QmVNBnz9YJFyGmUuULIxPkNLkDAURyIiN6UkkiAMPnNb6JyiTHpWakQN5PPirlqMlaUYeoNc@boc9DDs0uSLd1dbKZvmJqOnXeVYubj5eH14eG7xEWcVVgsunEgycvSD6ySZ1/3WWH5Bz7st/lEo0vZSDS7JD9dyWY/fPgAMw74nNczdRAf/JM4T8cuz@MrjNVXVpZSpfJS6nmsGSpYIp7PJ45Zll1ommY5nQ58zT5dFxyP8s@zZ5QXTOnhn/Ewkb9weB4EEaHRb4VTilF2saIoS8nl/HOjCkWr4KfAZHDibxm@MisW2RZ@/uZ//5s//Zs/ob8/pe@/U9g1@wSf6y7Df3J/6oTcCrpb3U94wQpMLWokF6xYrFiIHf8QY//JPk@YXH@28h//5OBj1I3W89kzG55u9GO0VI5yJzjAV/B8N9F6dA3BSvfRcbZWq4Fz5T/@r5C@/hLwYMx4DX7qRQ9XaRytp2uU5HO0XgKHnM9Dvv/3L34RidZH0U9RWZajY/prRnMyfspP5aeMgSMrrZQl03zulXcU@nhhWVnOXwTtGWpubFo/uA/5QLsyMzoJSm6fq5jgBnJ8CxzelVt68vzDJmMqDLX4WV19PkPwvSn/USYNn4zoBiP0pEdeFaLlWqrJs/d5NRpyTFXY/2Wi7r7/G@EiUe9eyPS50r2coPpFVC4vHzwfffWHBYX2iBgNaOdnzqbDPKr7HuZ1evYtcJHoj7XakYt/r1v4d3iMfz9XzLFn8HkCf/QPH9@Lv08oRAQTyOznyW/RXSPR8@j55eWbPv3Z@Ldj4F/rI/7tfcK/Ny7@nbTx7@gN/j1UmUh0bW0tmkwegWooePZrPqfwzWSawufxLqL7nX7Y8kHp4HmERdOXyfT9/Xnmh1GyWhX/oDRVfR9@uAuKdXmfTq/9UE8mz6l453VRzrX0ZR3KyotMPz@sAeLk2vnaWqZZr9fTlz/Uz9cmE4l0z58nsZ8@h4T1y/PzSPQO26KGP0v403bwNy9JWfLiYAGjcwVcjJz0EAGMLnRHfyT6Ye1DPPks@Syn525y8rV8/do8CP4PDkYQoY1yV6ad6@f6cgckIsupp7lxbjzKDcwDuQNOFf5yA3Bque4o18sZOUOWx6MJVA//Dw5M9/WBCdhMSOmOci4iznXh2Ts4eA34upD3FfxpuVxuBIUc5W7gP6ejoKbbpuj5QzNxETln0gcVRv@MHMvkYplSLKZdFkvWx4u7@3zpo5SKNS/OY5fVaNa5uMhy7Yjll6t019j9fbO5tb/ZbGaRj9YWk8@T6efwqdWTa@LxLFqvPrtYTWP7cf7LNKPZtWcX9UIa3aUkNFIewtayyW/8BCjhWX9yEYEJ39kZfs9ub265ixzkujg782PxJ4tB5KIg@ABodm76CQcDTfP39N85@M/r//Upi59fJhiL392vxemTwL9E4u7@7l781hPxuPDE1@APA8CPSe7u6@gkoDtwnccTl4n7ex4Gv/HEGkdYxzzW6pQ4AIQOG@W5XsSqoOHVFuNioeziYpTLJaotCPHN68pnWnNJVGk3ymIL18lgNiAvJQikuFytLgv3SrlaLQu3XCpVq0s@VA48wglAqqO0q8jo1WgCi8C5P55Dmwrd5xiLd9QuXuz9zLJgYidXcp8/@0HNZkezm00ML3z@fAEdKYZ7UWqVIoTkyp8/Qx@MJWDSt2@KVdAKTOHkbB6dMjiLa2ul5Xq9tAzuUjmRqErni3e8EPFesiIn2P1i9lJ1JF5GmGzFonwHS1wuryQo9D62mJWqLLrGntWBfR34sLv7KFGSLRcT8dZYTbDlUrycrIi/2pMEW8vWl5j4Oz8vJJeXVpaeX14GKgJ2@OqdUpPva3fKKk7376ttcTEibotTnj4tVKCK5Vz1ItJsbjZOGk28YV6SUJpajGEoyY4Irv1ZduycjDPFyuU5lvvyIhZbrT7nbVQusmisKuDSMZBCrFyh6kVhBqh1cUPsCIW0@K7KS/nCk2xx9F1pKwca8@cl/Jyfn5fz5eQSSKmlSuXy8pJCPz@hNOeDUfeS7uippc/lUvEyjarI1ai7BIWVVwrRpYhFO31WcqyDi6U2GrueQGBfcVgL17UdVde9yyhvTVvv3GodFbAf7jU2tk5S@TVAmd9ubKTyx6frURm9xcBP0QX0H201Ng9OIcHh3lbjeOvF7tut00MId2DAA2LBZ3CoqEO1qd4Oh7fob6r02dAc5epKsaymBZ9R96df/cFPv/rvfvrzP/7pz//gpz//01//8k//AL5/Cd8/5s8//jeVIv7@@pf/5H/@6V/9OQT@O/j@W/j@H7/@5T//Bf@S/6/h@3@Gwv5afENw/AukBGx/9Otf/slf/PqX/@hfwPdfiu@/mP7@9M/@N/7/f4k/dP75T//sr/FHeP7gjwHh3/3Vr/D/T/7q7/7tr/D/f/nXf/dX/8Pf/dH/RI4/447/51/@G/77t3//D/72v/mnf/v3f/nA7x88@vvLrwj/5e8h5OvL@TV4vqZe3xryy59Vnt@GGkEuxFR/@g9/@uf/ALj1n3Hffw8@@Pej/tD3@DFJmpqlk0HgHzL2OQvKT@75Zx8UUP6PGArB7PMkNgrNeaG//uU//QsMnoD9B2EMOXkWdhGB/dz@EGD/lV@wMOwf/vSrX/z0F//tT7/6s59@9UcoxNLLlVQjlZa/MLsBwOJXwCFg6WvgAFBew/XsJ@xJJA@OJ2todIjIyQ8fgKRPwAVK9FKkWABfRK6TW0Y3JIQ5yRKfFSdxrg/fUWS5Aj40AyRh2EjyqCRErSdZrVZLRkY1iCNQ8GKaEauXcf6Ken8N8GIinibVLINOyUbrhAVS1pJHrLlUG/GESQyoEwaGBcKgI0nOS8lybRMyrI02GeJC5MnIB3h@qNXLtVEd0f1IRQAcyXXIEqBqWLpR/Ufw1wgnwEdGmz9CUcq1ZLJehpAaVZVySzUpT7lIlaO6JxnVG8MZQyvYs@eMfSfJZYnPv4CUTEDjbzKAfkZWiGcQf5FcEtWhf89J3yVMD@00IvrwMB7/DIMpvQAAvOk07meCbzqNpXkO0SOOKknZwiPJMQDlksJc4wfQyJqMJKl9k@SB/KEMX/dZq4c8iA6rs7i4CK61ulSQDkCRZ/b1quMqNi4NkBazyqRSRcJg3EqiLh6Sqr@0uQS/MvxvPaEtnpwcS5HFGA7fMeblkU4WzGUzSqX3qkZ1WaKSJwkuEg3CuXpJ6zugFy6zRCRONyonaL6oWqC1RF47vXVzBDpgSpJScqnCzaRiOvneXF2t/Sgvr0TgSf4hXuYsrhWGZsAX/GSwdyFB63fpNepp4AQVoxSp18UaFZMj9eOtE0hwcsDkfC7DQHG8W17JLxeXi/lCqVRcycvLpcpyqVgugIQq5Yr5vFxZXq6UKyv3UKDn0M9Tq0ut4lr97818/qu/N@8zPxQ/kfo7Nsqww8M36ftIfZROZ/NU5JpcXKmOa1AQCorUSXviOvL4Lg2KJjZP5IK2ON3hzhsoWuQujay6AB8WWYiwBQiCD2BGCz0Ty8a7B1WxfoZX5fM1NEkuAjMkIhfADBxbxAp/IthwT0HaPJW5s1gKnDl0Rk7wmMg@ZADtYLA93HzomuzE5Jvc1tX2AxAbff5aqA3bBH3z58OsK8Y1j9rU8Aq6tutH7Sh4x4wz0Nz@AxCn1gAPhaj27w3D1qAFBUQjIgdYhx9bN815ACvs9PCBWr72j5PhchydJwPwo90XOyeh58lWY2MnUmLrB/ubU4@iACqyva3tE9@7wmO9pEUfxfutvb1pr3jgnOEJK66kUiD44AefKfrQM7P4gwciZx4eEdVMLiWDgG@O1bt0@r6l4hXix/yS9FFXNx05FuupAxjBoI/KwMa4w7Vn6jA9Wsxt5HDFIPsZpzdNNV8cs0UQeBWY57G1Yr0UlYpSuVbK5WFQobvbu0Y1WoIZ33nlsjZiBVY@v7SiznK1Uoi8xu1bFZkfLdCcyA7MRwZ4bzWei3YjttqBucmtQacmWviOmKHFHgyEBwah09Z6fRB6t6YPANPESEtRGHy/9QM41PDHfTzA5XlQ2EyMPgseufWtPL75hvl2HCEKznBfL53p8RaLaWBxViMnKILp1UEMT3e18LZ9OmYFYzs/dkp346sgkCuRCC6QaV2Wi2TI7JWvlIvlSiFfTpUr5eUiTBOLKTmfklfKKxXgkJxclkvlYkVOlZcrhWUQxxBbrKxEoiCytG42C6ONLEn01Iw23oK5hteJmpl@PRLlZgMY4vFla1HFDxiWmVQoX@QYJJQiuL91aVST8GWEOXzVnyxFJIW1WXR7eyO3vS1J6@hBG99GTpI66CmWc7mVdUlSKWYDhow8JOqjb6uEWqskaejZaGxvI4Yr9OTLiEOSrnkM9@ieZwXADPQUCqT2StJHH10OkJu8RGVK5XJPLre@IUlDXjw8AQhwDe5bpsJuoQcjMNE2j9mAOEl64SXKARmkIw4nstrx6ttoSNIu9zQaiOIlVb7IK/UKPQ36QCIbfMD5ktQDR8@G6bsktcCJ/C9JbXC1xwqEDcCF5/oMV5GkMa8H1kSSRgSttK8l0OZEOOQD5dnZUfpuR@3xz9jmzzZE7UKUNhpubbdevGj1ei173Nh6cURRL1/uKFfjod3qtUTCVhM@JqaCqOvBePqjYlSzqejzo15BlDEV1Rw3VSphU/kIJROfHmY0aL7EqJcQNW9FSCCEzwCAW/hZH8BzXWnxKO9DUfQctVpSFVkWu043ToyrpOjRYok7FIdx5Rmo58vSKspTswtK1bCcSBefDctSaUVaXYKn9EwqgHMUz8VyjEmxC0lKgGR8Jq0UpdXYs2fp2FP5GZNWKtKqtLIiJar3qDjEE3fd@Cg1quUgIJtdw36MPQ@eoKcIJeNEHbmZHRV3Y7TT6bOJz9raGcDhGUw8ILc/HLB1dkuiA7fLe7uLm7V1kBO5qoFnnFX0Lo6io0i9o7gKTDfW74arqwL2vtqrnSOCz/izlpbO6mfSJQvnW1zJQalOjXZ@ZW3t/PMl6Fo1uTqOwiiSL1dHUToRsbJcjYNqn6g56keucX3W0S72pFnLcd1r0RkOznNPSnLqLt1M3@uK4y7KK/nV8@HieVq@fPIk97m3Jn1fly4xe1TJ6C9svAOBVoUwj2RcBEa72geIZ6tp/g4GuVxKZHCTd9PsNumedfYhJOkwoVUTDSuxOL4khe8oicdiK/lYLBGrAvATCBYtRhzhNakE0hSatJIHla9qq@4QFIxc9d4ri58NVzdLciR6H@ngVZvLlUj0LnJ/d79W98bvV2w8VpJpz/uUsV4SZh5ZWkDApYcn5Epn6s9Zo9boHTWqArSxQfMD4JoLfvgonX3yrcsUybX6D/x5UcdlO8gnQsXnS3nZtWQ9W6/XLyKSJEUlz8ocLxdhVoFT7x@jdFMa27jrDg06Lb36GgmmrHIN5Pwy8eO@pt@VC@k67ZCJA8/fR5NrWVz/ytSzRK32Aa0OR6KGKZxop3ShC8RBsS5KOIVRmXVc@WHlh/IPr08PTg@22fPcanm1zElBy/XPUyk5JseAtM9hZNOOtiJR67NZlH80Xlajq1assBwrTKhOFzVx9jaOnBA/R6v8eeHy8hymJ5cJ8NVq@WdysZxcXpVXEtE6ngHMr0Tr5ICulS5EL6McwfIKS4CHLMJ5OVrPinB5RU5EnTT3QZpi1IlEy68/fIappXiJo5YnVzYrSrV4v3YP//X7c5h93dMk7J7@8ScLP/ccAP4R3PfwR/AJwYVhgvjLH9Nr/H@NfjYOeJmlElA8@qFWh4b9oflDMxqJVmL1ZDaGrxMW@wrEtAaVniWD/lRnCf9@CAKWQE9b8n3gXVtixTrM@tWlbDZ7kXiTB52lUimVS9HIb2Y/2SWYgS0tNFiMXzrCdSV6r7Z3yCQ28TYonDgvLaQ3jw82XsH8FJQl1cC34rGNg/0MRuGL24JTQm1dVWx9LN7cNkYo1LFONg7xzcynm4eU5ozOh1EozY9FLou7nVXx4oTUDZMzBZbP5YrZ3HJWLjK5vJpbWc2XmKKrMPXeGlnCtYhJGVVrw7TGXLONbyQo8UIDYTBuT4NpiaOusheHe5SCjoovLWxuvT5gB/t77zNeKA8/2dk9ZscH2ydnjaMtqMfrrWMmNY7Z7rHEznZPdg5OT1hj/z2D6KPG/snu1jEiyEZQXuHqBCeYr/axNWfsZN2xpTqk@00EO2b7WnUnwxXbUrJ4h95ksIG36qt4GfVk@NCAuV0nrFYeNxZgtjds4/ts29dKp2NH8GCa1mYLOCQvLKk27vSU@jlnhRWH7z7l7OIT1l7ej62wdm7fKKytMD0n/pi@PCgcsSdPnlwYUlVI40i4Gr5WGw7C7c8QFpRp9/uthXhpmS2BLptfTgQx@weHCznPt3B2dLIg@3FHmwt537O7vVDwPVvgW/Z922ebC0Xft954tVAKku1vLKz4vs2tjYWy7wMmXagEOPc3F@RcxCPWjal1FuiNQPHt3b0ttgRAiepELFos0DEVDISIDw2H3xKAJGdLS7d9E19HDjOc8RR0R/0StAc@AbWAmsc50vUyxZZMC34G6gCAIRntSI7Tm5/sXjslsOJtEjCCRO4iC1ihBawQwC/g@VSEY09qLJ9gEL3Q5auvcX4xTopJpw6dQvvOYWs4/teBGVJ0PQWdRoQUqniBV2ThXqCMd8mq06XtmAQqQ0klW0ok8LjT/uneHs/MgixMOy4RJCOPNAenaQE2qCL8YtUhlDcObxZqC6TVgtAg8CVjkfuJ1oxMtyaSAuq5sNAGBJPUvVH0FEOFKoVLgYgXPXwbNQBDNLhz4OLnvOLxNta1p7ptKlACibl1sM1riIuJNTbZygmGmRKlKJpv0P78mXm@C3fSa096jRjHLZDzYnF8vKQ1hE1g2IJ3wI4g6IAwpVxAjkkmITVUh@JC9VoAosOXnyf2SlmHjHIx9vQplWMNfJUYZYHpkpQjSyMIIhAEI/IhMr9oT6i4iYXsEi7b8zf0IhFxHOFX2rXG/l0IIFmnCzrVqn4v9JtzwVAdtzolkEVUt4NtDe5Cvgl@FI/AySnWgm6SYl6kXMJInDukmJpiXQiekqlNzQDOVe1AJnqsAJ2RWn9/k7cQv/iDwnkA1Rjk3io1GAiLp9h9idEXFlq2qlxXPSiQhwQFfItME0dCcLjH0x1tUrIl3l@QLTH116Tc3V71@IinBnYQnEZkxZkJ5xVRXQqsB0Az@AUy7L81QM9ZkiNLJgWEz2UCbGsSLp3mcPceX36hElvTtXjyzbVAsfxgLba@shq/XS1gWAtYBGoBIj4OeJMATT@TrZmfhwLGQkJBtfl5KGAADXgJ@vgEgq9ID0NukD797elhkF6d7srQb6EFuVTgSSa97UlvZ9KL3RdCFAZTgvwy@8xa6JJL4MLzvawMjg6XlZMJu5NeMi3UmOql6foSmOcAPIeikoMhA84KY5QgGQev31YG@AqIGmtsN3f3t04mYxFfxmmKgvfx7caUR2ISTBQI4504ehJ@ieJdJALXN@OHPI8U0bN5fHK01XidgvIl2FrQA6Z1APgRPWGiBvdeDhBqqG0YjzspFj9usKUEe4olSzFhGUDPV2ehm44KqB7MsTO08pRVjoP4/smeFMUeGZmTlRRn8QT7fHEBQ2puhckD63NhUDBWCh02Lqygssvx@DqIkPKegNnnXZMrGwgJ7KngrRNzM7vK5diyXWCu2geNe5SzZ/FTve5xbKNh0TuFaJk0KXOq9IJslC3iHgYYFydVm8e1SBobkQ8wFLsxhOFwTvarJOnnyJ4U6ylYvCwd9VvL8iWNdrIsaV6WNcp0tgy/ESY8mC5Fpk6a0nUWpuVaCh7GFJEHFtpNDjHIjkS4PSV0q1HcxIv33cQq3UaBMqUJI7nmNptxR9W7@Jbdod2GIR/VZUeA4QdjMzySOhI6JiMFeVB/mozgL63Hu@9g1JlCSC/7rdEdanHKMRLxS@a4qkWlChUDbWL4tslwhvjC9LAfmhUPNYVKnFgVWvG2gv3BQ3Y@cRENxzF0@qk5wSCeZ0N9Np0T57PNnDi8b2xeEu@w7Zy4q@FgXglAMDwQI47LzYkxzIN5Cfg9LkHE5XmIgOdhAl9exhPzmx761WSLhy7iIfqf2ENV3CqzexBiQVAuBQeG2jq6qQLTtjW8zngakX9gF1LGR4nQ2WGfrRIBJylOW9Om0XuYBCI6/EY39rLRKr6vfPSdnC8nUiGEIYx4UdxA0R/CyUJIoYRzkET5i6WZZ@l0fNTIgtN4g/QZPPpudGB6FyQwrUfgMTaAxcb3gBfwJiI/xmfmOV0uQLc6yzgUjvZ2bH554s6mh6C9SsiJMEF/2@zT35p9OpQ/9smflXWNnU@W4zIZ8q9CQFBHr4P/rIy8Uk/mlvimGoe5RlWvH2BfvIcjlA0/fz@ZrY9GSCCfp7yqEHoM@EohgbjCiL5BvlDzidPB81IH489SjaVlPw2XeEFvIKt6qPARvDmg2cRrNJtNuj@t2UTLUrMp8Rxo4MUBLzzois7G4zKgpTZNio1LaUVKSel043hjdzetGVKK3whbkxzXtNUmXoMkpTowUapJJLCaCNNXdasmic1SisMotfRwHo1QHlDBL2dCQDwXehl4@H7ML2fXDlfJ/IoqmVOZBXf2fUVuR5QbHmV@LCebX37lZbQBflfFC69sVUNBw@@6Fa90xUsPJs7ao0lfFIHn65Clz8EbDniR6NHEMNHWeFUAvTi3xsjaJ3l3f0gzV3WI3o6mHkQQcCrnPumQ3pDB6B6ojir0LDIPZaTgXj9RsIyoaYjfPQWNX50QDGiT94GI8qY826SDZsypogaCxbSw8ucSXhcCDXBoWvDrXxkCbv/SEHDjtSEY5Ik6cOOdIZiiKxzi@hBw0QUi8AT2loI7CAfKSBsM0XATPpQuNLmgWDjkY01o1KfISenHKYoQGR0vc40LvImktCpB1R26rGT6whKEn3dnSeIyMitk6dZcLGZIdZiHdO4tKInU76CRQooYimZHlAbSpiQmcSWE0sqrlzD5DPGOJ2JQfZ4KM7nVExFBTVJ@@mC8Ct15UpuYXiBFYPLACxMk4Fam8JuoSLlPrPoqSNBiYSiuuM0pN@51fLDgYQyeopaIPDKT@v/NPCncJP@ZTpX@v58UzUx9fs9TmUemMN88W/kdTgv@i0L/XxT6n6HQ/860@QdU8mmUsz1@Sl3/ohr@7eoXybwxDBt27wZNb/mfo4f9jhSBlW/SA7xSn8uP6QJfHp89NPnwsP4zR@nIb7InndLZttloNE4Gsn30otFr9BtH78G/nttLnl0tr2/err9Y7zQ2N3svexv76ptyY3nPevWu/P5F99NHFbT3nYOX33/SrXY/8u7Iuj1TD28LatlpDIcfd3fG7s766WDjuPh@5Ta3pRe76@rHTd3ZfH3y7tXJi@Jx8vbjy8OXnwa5gXPYzSmVQWHndentxvjMiBRvtNPO9p52MDjubJ3mB3ub2vvt5EZu77jyRs7tbd1@X9i4TRZz2V3r1cGLo9Or1tb3@tHu3vvOxkdTKX28vrV2s51Kd@Pq6G3koPBG3vl4cNDbylde7GRvN7tWJ5ff0e3i1bujw/XT9zv9V8rWYLt4Wnl3NT4s9d@8uXH3k73ls9LwtbOcNBpv3uRfGS9ubraOIi3FPLEL6pn5RrZubw/NymBFfbW/0xu8sWUje1B8mzwenNxubq3rH1dGhdP3Z29ul4/fD1@/efn9QU47Pm5tKSWr1ckfX50sR9qDwm7y5nTrtKy86Jy9Gdzs7hTfb2Zf99X9RudQv37R2/nePD7c220UnKEh723c6O9f9K9eX29u7Orm4bVuNJazRf2k8/7gIHL6UmttqjvvnJeNq/77bHH9evl9smO9OLn61L9@uX58elDOjw7HOXPDOWrtdEebR6V8OdvWPx596pqv5dM3ydLN1cu89r7xyY0UPo2LlT39vTowXibbve9HH/Vs8lSWN77f/fT@/fHOjd1qGKcf324fXdmvO8aBc5A7evnqdUu/LrtX1vfG8bHczr1Qr18nc0pkdLrjQBupJ0px5WSw98YabZofj3a/d0qfkjdn1wV18/robePjUa51a1jvDHtPG2zkOgdK463pbg1HL9qVm9PrHX3v44HzPvJ6Sy4Wt82us959u1x5l32R7F6/eLcuH49y@8ZRd7lk7799c6ZpW/13p5@O2sXtt1Z54Bq9N59OB1vJrb1R/5NazrX04/fXRuS0eHx0mL81XmkDd3vn6HXJPcjtvT3s7IzlxhtVvjVWNsbFzZFdKpxtvrPfX@8YVva99nF4mFNvkp33lrv8Rmt122@19uBV5Phl/3T/8O3tbrFkvxgY2vphObe/t7Ox3@ssvxrvvh5u7bWuOi9236nvrJPSdX5r/ay0@e644J5cv3Ir7ZtB4bCcPNEHbu80GXk57A9XDs/sj29H3y83Bi21cKS/N8cr8mDjpZUfvW1sHXzqXR9a5r68nR9nT/fMaz336eT2045TaoyT5dGpOzDdE3lUlN9ECrefLPel9fLN8cH6y4PvXyrLmnamXB2/7eQKp@Ws1rcLu6XSC3lruzv4OKio8qfN1wWlMOgnnb3rbGejc/r27Fq/GrwaXLUj5YrTXt/9fqiYW628nHu/3t0qqnvreyeyetp7dby8uZ87fNc5PP04OulsvBuevj3QcltXLyt7veV3R28rr1a@P3FOlDPz3St7PzIqF0xHLlWKt4XjSvmgbx8Xzq4q7vevrkrr@llLfrmbH6jbmv2uPC5fW5/6t73bYzXX6r3Y/KgcdbdAkp4e5pTi8Hp/dBwpvD0Z3KxY68n31@1X7wxZL59pK9mTj1eV637/1e1me/ms8emjUnxxpVaOt7Mtfbv4Inm08ebwqrd59qm83Mmt771V3o22@u77yJsdbfOqcnZ9MBrLb7aPx4NGztCLN8dnxZsTc/34bOe43H/dsrutnas@yIbB@PTqdnizo670R7flV/2rt0pu7115w3CWD3ORl@ruoHN08updI9nNqxX35uD9vnVWPhsVX5fNs4p5UNZeNbovRm8Oulu5FUs7OxmdbvWz6xvaoAwy5VA/tTcO3ux8f/bSykXyRmn904ZZXPmYvBm9L51lD5N7w/ftk/zgzLZ33mn29rubw3evjhu7yd3W@MXhtXLwfqt4vL@x4bxMbmsldbxTuHUaGwW9a0acwfpof2RblcL313s9GAnMTqXz4qRwZjiNRvd2t3y81Wi8cFq7L5XR6EV3BcYI/GydvTVrkd/w@8gi/Coy/lD4dQeRgdNrmSOQl/yIVoQO0UToEE2EH5uh7dB8p/FvskuRk/BpGHqPIjfwDFugrLGOicpDhu3693vilf0pNjAhuYautmnRE9G6ttYauuhzTB1@yV6Fh8DorU/qyNJNDd@Ggjez45zUVvlJM1BfMpEDgw3GON901QE/o6PhC03EdZx0mTt/bwxdBxhZaLeZ926sDF026b8p6wMoEJbRS9Ptoj2WTre7utJzwKF3yPUhcuzffo056JqCxg/MQt5rKnKuKLamorpKhTvB97Dsv2C6ya@K92YcCigTY7rqAY1UdN2Diq/adLQbVR/T3f9qJxPhOz6/ahdkOAy3cU@G0ZWIU3tDQd1Q7akNoBZP6K20Zpee41Ucz5eyYokVlaGmYrc0F9/W2OSvDGjyHL09b9bk3kM6cikWaLlihJoNXSbKnQNlhL6pVEgx2k6OBwlckT2qhqiiersNl5YsQkn7rhj3hDAvWQ/j1ga93xXqCdwdTZ3AawKthkArWpCeWbP/zqFNjj5QNcIX67fe7Z40xQsi@BZDTqnHd1yGqFz1fFaV1yBUflHy2W2ZuMMAio9mR34XL1T1xuS8LNG@R9weCa2NM@xgtyW9jRiLjtgs2o1yvnzJdxDmaOueR3A/zVPOCU9DpXoaEHRBbKjweeAr0/ENmhxktr6IuGurKgHQbk7vGMjUZr/fMe890DItXTGu0VXlW2VhvmC3Q41F1@SH6oGmLL8uYv8kzRGw3pDU3wYbFFSy/WYhALEh1mvmUwO7M@23xzS8hf2s0T6GefizLl032/EgesnbcsPrlvBy4vBTWR2gJbGLO2tNe8wzQvNMvFoFENynQzJBNbzdqqFa1wJqIDra1BMqBfBt1QvC891qUM4Ue7y0PKsnxA60A2h@UflmIIQ694t1ybN6WBYCvRPhykwkDYjjbSECZ3aJuaYFROgKjoNhjHiE706doQrf6eVzEeN0Os9dwj97Fvas8o272KFUNHuiCElgN8YZ@lTh/EIjaN3vOphVwHrUULiDG5tQI15kGszwMZxpyeREO4WQn2tIN5klidrxObEghvwaCdIL2hMM7YmD1uBbcVmX7@DitI5MkWgNMvr82e8w4PW58dA7xAss4b8bFhmccybvy4KgVc/vdULfTTEBUXypej@7lx65uwcTcPPW0kaqHgeB2cSXZFgMgsSWJcviDoLwty9BMDY2lV3IqydP4pDqnOCy5Uv2lMXltbX4SjpOQd@VEwm/M4rk@VDyUGIQ0vU6i@eX4gUv8TImBpSFSQTL8xHkOYLlpbjsIcgLBHIRMHAVg5B8x8qcaycRl0OIfbyXkzD4qo05uS/lk/Ll2loZ93iGAqcS5@cXfamQzENijnohORnD0fKIUPjlZI0AeSEfGkdCKJaTBUDBs05ORgS5TkX4mYbzXL6cOzj9zpQX75yGN/hQcnyLn2qfl7G@yKl8U7rFwG25tgjENylZ9D6lIIyz9BKyOegI1CUht76Kh6ZS/H1aYtAC@lWnRsXQ4QiCQDFARPDwaCl29dhY1/r2wQ6Bu2Tg43VOMTnFyjANAYkCEqMMiUGEEA20XrM9sHw4GIrLCb7jmw9glMk@rjjj@QFoJ1T7vZxIjHHy4Qo34GvTenmTxhBO3zgkaO7truPj7dYR7pjd3X8BTbiA9Uix4Ner5hOO0a/ihmLw9zForgZFANnGJzSirrypJvPHQC9/gc1DLuCnsfOEVDuEYDyx0A6JLzS3qZkCGyelx0eqS3Sk1wP5AOVEFeYZ7FZlio7kGPNXlZb5W4To0BulJlKBw08oCogUQpqdHDX2j7cPjl4T5Q6bjb3DnQZihglmW7E7jN5zgR3EMFSdD6o@PSM4/IKE5nVSWt5LGeglvATLX4LGiQeATYppUuh0ibC@nOln4HnwvAQkUXxoUCqaHdWagxv3rvpgojLOHIS8FXmpxVAoyjRvJKQBb3Yk9ORoHSUd0dJUHSPmAmPTez8Ug8uTrIdvHWaZ9CI06rmoR/WIX2z@lqhCnl4Hi3zkDC1cHVY7Upj8SrutOnRrRkB9QKnqXcpESJYQoSBkfu0D@cHPpvhjr8BBb8OjQTfn672BmjupLIL2yGn3s3TckILEsXg60p2nVpJaJHLmb6edUB21SZXxocx4blc8tyvIjQtcdjWtkGmX51cTitg88mgeea64buxpZlw98beSU8t1odM7fbznhWwhXOpQg2Ez4X4h2xxPyLqnXpM99Xpx0BPnK3ePK2WCsJMamRhwgvFTTJg7HSBbfMa2QSdXaPY1tLH9ucdQb9FDIyU/6ORNMQieOKUJ6rQH54lPPEP1IGcgJpCGdFrmXGR3SYOKjy8uELK0V55ESNegU5jCKqAZIC2Cw2mirqRKmo6YKIYCUayKUdjueJ2cIIPBzO5MH@hCIAzlBw6DUwn8GB/PqIxOeutejVAjhwQ6K0VwXTWdhgQJbtcgnQbELdaBiqe586tRnq2GqJynk2n8BAyKOuGWuShA0M8w74FQL/Pq3HqH6uEdhsPEiVDFclVxgsI70Xt6yApyoRA6/ntwts9KpeB0MN46xZbzueDIMd4/xUqVyM@ykwX2BM6P2HFEgyJbIc/g1B10QVXXoRPzR0fDoR/LxqfFI/4YV33laonPYB0hjsXQ4LABvqO7peK7qHG91mXySM5EFkAonoTecu4N3gDYGyq2YrgqP2OJglys7GKGlBB1WNV2@BvQ6R3gIPHxFdUwLNgqNwBDSMds0yZJxEHpoKWHA9qNlEKF4Ua18RoAzRUH/RdI5gh24KKhzpnAC/SEQ93jDU5CIRKoR6ORhZORhmWkHje9CFee1JWTvRyV8mRPpiHNe18oFoDIK1iFaMzdkQVB4JlhhubjS@IFS16X9IED0T/PNDg7yPDJqTcPF2j4GDM789cu5xhjiLva4TFoJDYxESqq02XCOwNHEsA7AtX27BAciB6jSxqeCBefjSIF8Q3iGreFM5IRpEXQKEVDio1ch7t0xMViFL3gvzGZ@LkGvS8hdgaMxYE5/3ikgECWT3AIcTZyGgL7J4cYhXFAKXhHXcoG@w9GiMM/74bimzjEm4WjOyHmBYiAz2tJ7eLl52fS5tdC9FHKlB9Jmy4pRSVCfXk@GK@yAMPahcCgUCSPvEp5YKeHwbk3D5BKTwapxwo/kdvXFl5kNwM0QYmvLLpPiHthq5uHFBIPzBuVL1KJbTVCzQy1D1eSoBEFIxDPUr8XpgpBA08q8NK1Qim4zuyl8SQJxYhDv7MiR0D5jqW8dxzYE@i@mTM41zuvopyTvap61aQWpLcW65pFQ@NkXUW3CNc1Lc9WdiVUWe@U8URlRSKvnrP3Oxjg6OrmLb9/AQcUSZxclr7rpNh3HVwMESHhMcqjxjz5N3nWOdQhf6gFPdKvn19WOjTre3hfFWuHKNrD/I7pEG/O6@T4ilsaAmQEN42qt7mep1pYEOoMKD0T6fIJYXb22dlD0e2CvKat@nh/6F7ewxRwDGGpsR85HhqCPqn2BLAH9pnkPBYg4cPiq7vDsCEuEpJ5opN63IERyaQYz2oT1uDgAPWDjBjGImRn6Ijyo@lJpsyWYoxxfJicj8NLIob7oP9XwwUZP1gQJAetEYmxzl8z4lci3P@2K6OB7mYJzQ30LisPPx@FIib0t2LO0wPiVqAv@LMDPh8I6wZC0faUQTRsgQIPc2N@NDrFIPcH4YMbRj7yBT48mgcp6QaQcDK6aiIskHgJ86FpkRWaxMwWk1qHKGrxNpksNzUkGUJ87LwaT61zRJbNp3EZkDuT8kytJtAxOuRM1rgqv/yDVFm8/JnmqeHbP7Dhl7DyuGQZzLMsPBzs7XYgFNrA0lV@ckfeazYOdv2rrZh4J7jqmBjkZEy7l73VrrUsB4wci2ur0uoQ@zleUsVjmlunMJThhVNuhh2rfLMC6r2oln2g6aQ6THzARHgDlgHA3S5ovAa@dr6lure4f0AgcDLhwkK04oAebhpsbJqtoPSKOJnDC5CisjtQ@B4QZtiiF5i3FddRx2oWE2ZbOvwMFLztNwtT8izWMHtgqHuQ@hi6hJq5Um6UyGaoYHRyeipXum4ukkbbEcW4@Epk2j2CNgSXXgveMqFt/P2pYpJAdyWahj5mBl4B0FPw3dyM3tIKWSHn3UI1acetWNShLQ8qzSOWc5USCXtHjHCUDsfvTAbiiokIf53nKp7vcExkF1ulvamUfGJPy9SeDN4xJzdR8Hn@ZFgbL@f68j4Nf4tHNhtKaxpfs@9j3h4Puv8LyP7Qzo9sFs2jlq6MmXSr0D3LbGN5JVdaxbmW1jOIDbG34CU6IY1dHVn4UkzcGIDjuJdWV29UnRWwGd9qzhAAj90hVCkStWylN1A8wHhhlWE2oTu6aH49caI/iDJNfTKki@cmWDCjxpNpjMkBNjrBJUYVJKYIFuOCmgCpBT/PcMuzaVpsFRwdtTXs0WCA57K8FHg6Skm1MIGSqMdbiWfwXIUnFJ0uH4V@jJ2/5t9fhfuJTI2dQze/ZN4ChVSNUC2g69d46ateehw5ECy0ogMDNl/VgBFhiTXFZJRbCQAaxzB@ASrKamEoUA0PpGPuHqDVhjLkm4u9GKyiJS51fHBPyRIL7SkBkYD3TSFj0hVY2axnGYk18PWmnmc9xmPJahTn7sBExEe9JZ8c3v6FLt99skZ3gjG6sZPImah6u@rlKrv3AHEPCGo4uLMkHfN2DqCGaePaTLAjBUgvebOwx9CGClD4AiQ1HLIZjkuhavAN3pfc2iVUkOlo@dJbw4LwWq7qUYO/Ddlv/2Ax6ylvzQWq@BN6t7J4UVM3LrX5QgytkogFpomy4uAleIS4g@MSQ3yc8wMFTHKDsCaS0TTlG1R5QbnNFYQF6pxpGlJSbMR6aH3n06cUGwsvXg5OmEa1XGpck6sRFH14VkE1hoM7nIykeJKhlULge6aCtK9G8FfM6Gyeud@7YZQgsY6CPEKCAoPOvXA0bdzlUky@r1LObXpzEhfxoEfM8v7cvVgXBuJbPYepCP1f8mFi9buOlOL54ZIBOWTPkb9MBblxIvqlHo3N6/goNQbRwfA8Ul3MOtAtjPPkHYei6I4SsU4jBAzaYZsKrjs2kXZx7wYy1hzVYILUHNfQhsfv/0KFl3cLukAG4VcZAKbTCAgzVOYpuxRPZAbRN0omMR4mdZPxQ2sVZ9le@pl4bD3Cz9OH8d8Hl@QRHZqjVHOc8PalQIrmeIlI4G9PuZ@pLhXvt6jvTHmn6jtDD7@@D9DDr@8sPX9WfX2L8TuqCAwx9MA5Dk7Zn8GMGt@m7gVyO8UzhoG5YITafD@demjh216mUtOl/bOpTcsyHbx/eX4JeJ5zCkHxoXDI8xnPYxXcMEHOcvORXM5B18Mr0Z0I7@K2ifpinNz4Sjs@foE@qXPbthijKQAxV8ii73vTU37IICGGknCQJxL9@mFWXKZydQLUtmvaX1xjoayqfsGponwOxiixX/sE494QjlDVafsilMZLgoRKsHlJhqh3YLrpJBg2P4mgupCPk6mQ6mxuKq8RMbXYXelpQiR2pF0@Swq0bim01tQk6QzsGtIn/Hmsb@8dJT0G541Blt5Y0hulYSq22yVr2wbfiM0OhXUKjz2BCu/2bXPY6zO8KAp1QITlW8q7Jmr3qF2CVo@vSRziXTWr3ra4eFB9336cZacWg0k@nZ/Hnvv6kG2g4t8aoy2Z2wLioWFC7LBaWPB0p4XApL1Akt4HvuSGPm5xCLKnNgsVYBP5AYrwGi1xkP0RsdOcjL1BLC37GoikuK46sFzUrDVeBax@kMzCZZggIWoA3h1fpKws@KDzC8vZOFRaKl24uHvAKvNKm5tbSDqGOl3IloqmvtwjheNWxGnbDRQHc8fSbKq/h/bzc@Wr1zDv/wJrQqYeV6YIToVJLm6OBmUHj@YN8PWceLMG51SYgQPKfdPGueE4NRfzLdrjqHcptzD3oqkywiUzojh9mM/e4Eajualpxa2vQFPR0QFEBCUg1YqvneF6Gb5ZC1O/pumon5hPgB1S5fDeWV4Ms42rzF7iWUrYZltVOw6qrAryCpUzjscbRHf1Vgk7mtLDGSLM1D3R6xWH7NE0W@xrbX4qY@MQi2KrH4eazSfbWJoMtCXt@wFW2Oir7WuCxffJBNjTmpEGshlu2uwy5@NQsdHkYNosGXMiQsbzkeZI7MSZ1qOEgKpOABPn1WaVkBAwqp94FeQUW3n2OjTVeDKPNuvgKyFijnjdg7AZ0StZQ7YftJpkGMgr3yADw7MuTuhqDuEJTb9TrDvUURabVgbjUBJOVjbsQ8Wy9aTGLzGcqGbIMwHEBetkbAij2IZi@xjiNIyLkZhLmi@DV2agMasHgNMc2p9jhejrEw1IOUG3ieUdOhQU2C8gmuznceQ3x4Pp4l4LWxVTCEyTS6Qok1m0NBTPYjVMIx3GzMFmEQMcgiW@tv1q/4naj6ECZKDsAQGDx9/RwthW0FhJRRezT@jpVEtkZFEVkAODoe4qhmoOHX38@2aEyAK9MFHozhA0Ju974Z1Ux3EaxmdnWXwZANvNHtB2N9ybgBN1EN75vVWMkU6EqMGGG5hinGW6OAbjpLwXPOEyUfwE4/ZEHA6O3p6AqRi8MgEtPbhNwKUzXim@bQBEJx0XM9wMpfM22Cltd0hCtG/i5grcUzpEexDu8bDxiBg1CQpsrAsiNy3V5pkBt43NIfPGZ@DX4KpPEJDBXZsaZCqGPsKPshmrhXzPBxLAg7hDqHDLYU8NpQHxCwUHcLIdQbm94a2lChsFDm58dQtfh4g5ULbwRNwaPwMXZPizc@OrcGjzxSwR91S6HF4rAJ0tZCXj@@zjT8T8PuFN9Kf2P5HK7Nm6PFjOUGJvP64k0K6KWbOcN4HVqrTRIq7VcKfGGp6wgH4JoOfa5ZMarrXwXRtkO8NWvAUGURW73YcqQXtpyDCuTXTqaB0iG8zh0OztX2XuMEBfw1y5Am0MBy28kqZL9PKPadK6BxrJASQeoE5QzsHRS40knJYEfr7ArZ5kP@4k/L7Fs6J5CU5@ANC3I@EIKspE9ktBGPQHO5t86nTjwoumkDySBf3nIhCvKRH30c9E5S@9m@v9KV@@Oo1RfgRjIjCeTR0JQ4OXG9ridGva13zlCM1uJPldRSO7N64F8g3LmMiz6OEivxPE8ZUMzzgXvNaE@jMOLH3F/bKR1@MmF4Sizg/08INTAYH5Gl412LTs70bOcd4CEdbmFqisiMKdUTwtX7nkgt1nHm/NldsQ@dmgXPjolqB1LdwVeFsLUyY/12brXaFdTfCGgBQcgdBeydH8LkySXh5pQkNQvPB8jkOFT9Y8sKo47pQOh9zj9J@X0yOf4BXVqOe83sj5o1bj3BHk4W8Sboe26i55xxv4frIJ8tObS2v@Cxx@Ht1IYnBzapWNxP4uOmk14ju8Fqbm34zX@BxV0oWF8bdQh2jhbxMPbPIScbPoBjTv8DcD5jlvTM3yPMHY5V1/zlEVscmTv@4AhneGL1MQxzfAGzaGO27CX64XHdRxM45LvBMa6dNc@gB/z@t3iu6Y4iozGlh5IofWC79tJcbrgTx70e9awy4WBVf6IU1wQGX2dMqTri9yaGsuX/DnlCJw2nc4RBy8/ydCuwW9C/X5qRWAoiMrYoVfJDz3bOKIXmyj7gobGa8BW2qKbEUdvCuMsBK04B26zoZmVS9stQePIw1L1HFiqC/5K9@ZyCY3Jh4e7O6fbB01j7bebh0db1FK2sjvHygeWlmylDm3eLm3IfDGnIkLcSJntgbjOI449J4lnIEft03XZdsw3VVhOn6tQEplqEYeXHPP7z0cd@qo9ipPf8KVeTp8TzuNHQ2PCA1xqxLU75ZPwPnycNxJcOaHMZAupMJdrzreZMDfCxVBmQnCnMeg/MSe1DLpva4EIU424JBidt1b1ADFbGJyjRlGGr0DvVnNiD22HjSaHIL7EvwLEVABgPj/t71nXW7zuO638BQrUA4B4k5JjkIQFCmRijm1RA5F2c1AMAyCoPRJuAUfIAIh4Wl677TTmTSu07i5TC9JO@3ftpM0M30E@x3yBHmD9Nx2v93vAlKyYk87okYksHv2nL3vObvnglq3syKFibbXKnR8B3hOZCOxrhzuFWTvu2W1z2S3iaza5nYhD9nqDvpPUuI9waoBcW5waOUxCPWa7mIyCgISqLeAngKxp7lF3KASygelSrFcen0uDYJH7K/IW8ErmOS/op131E4/Nn5SnNm@jgFg8TjzkA2dEzYp1oIuPlqTa1AXIrQqhF7NnDzZmlzQX/@KLcgTDMildje@HKPx12vPfWkz6y/sY@HLN8OJncCOVY6evrEqpvPXZ7Dzf8Vq5OXMRS6yonhjOhFvOiEB1V7GeGJ5ZZm0j5Hz2N3jC3u8ajLXP77W7pZwRiGeTO9ajqKtiWDjKs0H8WhEE/lySvSOBr2jVv47U4dPbmuMLUDQ3Hi145dotWUc4TS0/FKa8CZQzwUq7ra2/typv6Zrq@2jSvtohrxncJGGa06q66pI025zfq4cNXC2dGEdX5r@omFuzFu0U3nrMk4ro8vZoe/MuGRI/Z0vBWNKmyBvY4mRxeG13BBzMlttm0SBK1cdhXiRo7Ia1zzafyG19aAHg8tSciJmX@JLXTMr2DcYiIrOBrQ9yIbHyEEZXMYmoXSHRo9FEjFZaBGbEPMC///F2spMQTbweGNk9RUaWb2xGnljNfLGamSR1cjS1dLEH5WOvH4JWLOuKpwC959aggW1vafef2frUB2@s6PuPbr7e@pbe4/U@1sPIGVP7T@68@7uXQX/dx483FFUwPy81xmhyr2Cod/utDt0O79aLt9QhDkSoPyGetjqqXcG7c4LmDzrfqu3@ZS/FPud8QaX2nnRGc0G/Bw0RGWWsVhN0F0RvzXpGye0uD6CmdzDd0TtyxPrSN48fb5ZItsLCoduDLj5bY94ENLjomclY7QB8ANIBTQtfpIl3Wl8Wiem5biopOPMz0v3IDCF9x@qrQfbGOlze/dwd@/BQ3Vv7wC@7n8L3eyo7V10G3PnEWYR4P297d17u3e3KIErUC4qvFsjg/VFVSgiOPVK@/nJBMODdVEqlG@OV@@lVKo/0FYRvlqe9AP3PccwpfDdnZ2dVslFe@ba1sE330OupvNtlU5jkEvLobpYIFwro9EIUJMo2lV2po6sZaHCG1Jvpq5hdjVFd0D0Oa808iy9E3sdlb6L14j4IE1xs5lh06iB0FXAjai0I9iaoggMy8v5dUK5AdTo9kBTw4vVE/0Fi26KY1aUI5e0l1afkGJwxt1@m8Po6gSY96zVTWTHIwbACyFJYAC8g8GEcet5ZxcvSdRNgZiMUfCHhLc54VlveO8UuUY0cJWEOxwI5JbUiceNhhQDHLW8Po@jY9bEuwPFSKEiPsGjk5xuV1@5kkoc8P/yxoavsgCZhl3wBFa2FiqCZzeYDbC3P22djH2VqWXxNhhEkE7fY02tJ90WiHt0LzxCg6UXqEZAZG/V8GdDO6rXDCcF4tQizNFMufUw5bbl4O9cthyUvBOhiHp71GhUmJL4TxdW4E6kAq@CBhAV7P0C3QoNx8TYEprBiUzljD@AGQkin/rIjWo0OJ60O04BkXUyz7zvfCcrnZwPilgqPlQ7o2GHoR7wIeQUfVCRmwsQYkhT8im@RvEYZtwWBG/DPVSGGGEFP9SdK9Rs4UFTFE0cIYr8fALVoxYZw11IlWY86wab7WtofEbR87fPZnn0THKEYrKR5nz054xKDOjZaYRuXk4UKhbNxlQTDu6QCvaOj5Rfqn9wq7axfedx4aMP841S6QlvC61jfrxgpUR@ZiGRHJaH0Z0kbUC90gRpyp8cYWmtz8i7Ja5yjQwYl6ceMN@bzarJ42vVaHqf4mW56ZR4fl7jUgWyN6EphJFkgt0tr@qaZJ7KNFRWEAR7J1QWPevqlDzhNPv1Jsa1x1GoQo/0cR8h9Ro7rBrp11jervFBD3aWlPBpPNwGf1bHIpcZRT8ZezxKH2Tu1HIb2ZKGosVkujOjt@i8xlzJSqvmOLx0XkXQbS9GB/v35dHdWlg7Ph5eCtv2QmwvVbdCLhkXH0sWrsuj/WgBWj7cXgkttD2fjJgPySg2M9PN5MxfW9Jz/gKKH0bGjtYeoMGzFyOqGqQWtUm/ix7iMnwpDlWjAlkbTcAQPTzc3jk4UOkdvGVbg7Kw77X6bbIvxW0QcV/Vno7YDpk2u6JhmkyYIMM86ZQ5m5e6ZBct5tjOS9gqhAfJS3@YzcJE7QXJZCrWEXyyEAuBhte8Ieqec2t3pvcgvy6I53XUhFLBoFkNTMU2c4kPH3ayT5tM0G955o39597QMDOdqTjroqvq0cxGpBlhPA5aT/DlO3783mf@eE3TYQar8@0JNRiV8NvoL189BMJDfCkuuiO4YFj0kJLOCs3SJd13ZJbncthffEKZWOxz4YWtbV2YY6ka88fXrEh2xJ9u4jv/TDLbPbnv1Fs8pazbA5oNDr2MewQBkwlisNq0ZwUUb8zlCKPeMOdkzTDk9lq7RrWp61pSNDPBXU0Gegs4@Jtvh7eHMCnYbReSKrweUnxKOJSsuFtRCjoTML998@b1i3CHW6GLF74obj5DwvvnuDd80bJQ@jOfVIVg5u4@yOv8YAIs6LoaSIHHGb1gQgWB1Yk5U5y202Fk1w/qcjpCWzyozN6jwzzeF4WpZtU0VLd47Hwi2dgJJNIGawmbhvKqifT@fDG5OxTU7QJ6V1@eHi82BML78PlvOUzmwWCIWyUw4qMme0UFkXzNR624MZbg4IPG068VA3NTx7Gsc7y5TX7hRhtpprg5HjxHvX4dOVNim6XxGarYaw3PzvGC65yuTDkPbQKkrJdXm89YR4Uja24eD0iJ4MSEstzkWrppsM2/aNrBN9dQfZDyGMB6wKyZDlz@2rICuWcNbxV0qMnlHKcBf2KSCpwEc3WMsodJX@F0tEvwht2ZSS9x@nEHA8@Z1HXBctoyES@XNwQyHCFzOS3AdFfrncya1O0m@zZnAxtjkt6SyoBs2R2Y1KucijpVOqkuZSdBUoOTQJIySUsChQeTN7bnkt/pPG/SIEu0OUC4nFd9r9soiv7U7YzIjlkx4RjzQEL5Tv84RYNCMU8NKn0kbKJrWZlC9U2vUSQFStmAUCYLBpYX0qYXFLCBId0KfcmTiotRBfC3VEKqak9epFzffIYzfNTx25OO2pmijK9jI@pZSY5BltTOg221d08d7O3vuKixxk3kUaiUVtijUMxSMWqOXrJ5GPDBZPy0yYn6azj3tMO5GgV/N0D9wcgC4q/hXE2AUDRwWaqz8@NzVYfDe2gGJXOcbcig6xabNhTbg0l/fHY@PafhnQKnV4QpcFvNi3hJcDvSLbIShcPW04He4jAsJPKVTe1WIaBCKURlKr45BmJxHVrz2blgS5n9E4YOViZt0kFATtgmcScYIMuzJvEtoTvaT4OAm/SWXVOZTLhieCgVi5HknPq6CdzYsSPuusQuSSSXROQbARGeYQZP0cc4ogG1rDoeqHPvXBMLDhU8@m@FpR3T2@i7WYbROmJo2Tkw5YaVza8SVpuPU@6nyIKTEVRuvFF53eAFgUHeg928xnPcAaP5HQEzm4MG4wUUgaNV4ADyMokAUvkoxmZ8LYOlF1MkvsbBeoxWJ4FKgC6mSDyVoNLuUARrPTQa7QFwZxyQBD80QRC0ztfYkYNpEyGctFhVuKBMRRJnmkwzw3@yMTT0Ns0QMB8b@mOlwaY3atkuthDe7RG7BtJ4q0NwDyJ3Knis2emVcLp9JKkNq3gYwqpUCBhwhk6qi8eCPYk4SadoqcXLioy2JBo48lpyNMKW07BAaQolgBZcUF41ASyAIghxcXiyWKC8El3QXDyoNfkJ3sYaqqu1Gg1oLh7UWh8RrIU4rC5oLgwa2ddoo3T73jC0K5nFg5dN4GNtdBapzrTTnoz5pNFOK2ANjWF52IyWQB97T7zxbRUwWvSpCPXBSXvjlnjE1mkg4N/8umF9qIBmte0qCNkAIe4WFi/lxRDm6yibfQsYc8M8OvAc4hrfxy3QOkHYw6DYA5NURDMZItDoU0yzYnbXcKnpWFXJGEml1dIZfJ0j91tfOmNxhyO/p/Pp7DzN1ao6uyi0SSeLfLS@rvuiOB40PRX7U5XKE47BULk4ikHSgh8Hx2RsUvGKI98dtPmyM4@4qlpYq0M6CuD0sBPCga8p0bbogoCmcXE98EEligOrkFOLGmXj0EJVFMfKpXFogS2Ko3D5epA8FdeWty6NgwXBOBylS@PAGRjt0/TSGSCY8@903FRz@gPNoiS1lT9yp4bB2XK@HYXbokVVhfaChMGBn4a@xdVDGHN7rnctMehS/YFCR7Q/Mh6vpA04imnnLvMFcwVLZiPrhYVbSuUbWGvlVdU1f3wMB0HxpGvWd8ziD4nooUsSQUj3HijEFNtPRyAi4WgWRfrQDAjhhPo3m6ia1WzSzdD@wd43D7buNx9s3Uchaon3KLy@QW0ZUtcpF1cxnj3ftjRJp6imUNUCm5GifdjKo/oJmh06RShyLJZaOrPg5mlmoJBSje6Liv3OqboHWRS0PoITIYvmbgaGJ0N1MJt6uvAinQ0g7RNMt0rktQ2oCcHwPJGaEIyVnLKELS7/uM8aKo/7j8cMeKTqbJPpN@z6PkbDJaugUoUXj8fvdUZHqEtSME5LeRRRBR9lN3JOhSoXcoMeYLAG8LelkrqjneKK/Vqr20aXt5MTcnzb87qt3tFxqzh8Okyd@DVxT5NZPvHRyWUKlal2D3cOHjb3MU7Xzl2ynMCfKuUd7t7f2Xt0iDkPIeu6JO8cHOwdNElB/eDR/iF6DA0lpW1AwRKASYID9GDvna13LRj@npZKskGID/Im/BFXPnnlDZtT@j0jM488q0I0KQgPmalgUUrLq7HX6wwmOngb@p/QB3weLU/wUQZo6ajG5JAmg9efkhf4Op1bUFSP0WQ4JlDSgM@EeiLrlmCYnv8EC5AvIh/4dtKmL/KNMuahId9gmAmVRQMZLJYS@64Tn1YHLpOHs347o9GJI8/8WacPkPjatDwZnxRuLc@z6FVySEpD4cLLJTg5SuQcdTm@pPSgaKWnrCBG9rVrNaUN3gGKLEpoEALLFCrAL4hVlct52bOUHSBKsmBX5fhRZ8qyoXdhJH7NFWuM2K0p6/kCfZwg5pNY4Jg5wl/37UcpmmDyPkXGHHW0PDd9Rn91Y/mGOWNGJ0PvU4FddxG1R@5ChbfGGXb0Qj77gnknz11SgSZmhEfczQP08jYmDSaCPMf9cRU6ajyaKbYg9Memu6DlDfw9FdeubVSgycCEy9qw6TTnsjtKNBLyxwxAYl56I70WuLFhswSjOMwQ6zZEJQ7iAxtiNQ7ihQ1xPQ7is48ZxDvJ5HJ68DbU6s2brM3sjGdM8f8wxQsFDbuuVaGDwoDPLq5PY0aywzgEOldDc1D7zAbkds3eXlgzF/Vn/wm4bVxSqkBEuOILqr0A8@d/mF7jG7pL9NLfcQutDQqZE3nyYhNmvC@8K1NcV0lsScPYfrEAWzqtRzG@7A@DGfFBwqT57JcOTPy0@USPuzL9p1@4rgRlK4FVQxjBf0UR1F4GQZPL6/VF3kbZgBezV9cMFt2CAAGDXLdBVsMgcSTPF5Is2/gqsSQrNkj5MiQ/@5XQlPMrBuInBoL2WunMWND/cRYaqeZDoThQnyHRpmY/ePVNBH/i1sEuFge@H2CnIo3F9f78u@F6ByVj4f8odnJSAXt@6WGP7fh/uiyO64k4PmQUhUJivy0zRC6XCPHZz4J6cPeGl9miRfL5n1xcupxc@g@C0sExv6EPbuYaNLLwFmjUg9xMKlo32Hj8oANMSkxtrGPUrDlryeFZLAZjbgMqJlssztzsVZ09i82@brJDyOfMYGkuCf3rEWO0zhEGiTUKPpOVLzNcOnOjZnNtWW6Qze0ysy4G5tA3hscRUxyL6dkICRwrjpARRS25WWH25inigquxwo/fGrWe9lsYoNUf9IsSAcQblHZ6g2ceHlSjErq5KD7zk6ShL8JaEwKS42oovm6hQgVUVZyKsO43y@0I2Gq3J71JF9/QaiJXoWOkUgldxpEg2J/0fMGJJ@6dideFFtSQUwtYRBDzhlBLOoWBlb4U@RDpOLJRkqUS640XyQ0dJVHd2iNvOCZitagsgC6fiEEFEt66BatZeDRQPyNE7Iq2Ju151@t3MhY8RnH18lYC@UXI1bhUlWZGuE8sHHnUAHkw6TkYzmTESTemxjlFHy1@MuX8KvZcB@eNGnUwQoixjvB8tSo@6Mi1DCIRC6KRi2U1fyPLvUSI9mF69lyIG/nVMhIaYha5KCLP0EazvHVCbovIqJVwEDYDTaMAHGGAXvp1owytgwxTr1r6Nz/9@B/S2bNSSadRTB2v3wKZgSKSBFjx6@FgX3@30KN8IraKIdz/GOBm1MedttdrYYSasYUaJlcCZhhAxHwGEw2dVg26sN8MnmQsXzCaIE6sUmlre1sdvnOw9z5aQ/ElAs2CUHGcBGsqneNup5JOvigGI4jMhCjMfSGMQLoSUSjTKgQzLSb3OicZSwMLeut7f0a9RXf5A9R053UZQojZaXbqg/eEqFtrozUDoWcwjsP3/pQxD4asPRuPeDBMy8SEj8MOTH59FZmJtIsh4un9@kd/SeTEogR4PrxX6dmkk5h@yq3LhSzN2UKlkdgqhwx1QiLiC7vo@z8nZD4H6dYbYeqKvSsaJPHN/snfKsKBjw8welZJ5eDJXYjoE0ZkXg@o5xLxFS7E9wPGd@zRK4CN6GjmNvE@nJPFERoNZazk0gXd9@sfSY0B3hvjm8kCGitOdVOxg/Hv9shSWRmOpPG18CeO8I9tpGLmmoSRD6pYPB//KlimdjPZdTLP7yvW6gxVLbbBH/933OwjHXNYPegBnNHaQxW7VhLq/Nd/Y/BPU1emF0yY3/z0058FbZwmtmya2J5Pg9U0jbZimlT3K6Et6ffxyEjnpolD8UuXjLNypzXraxKCXyT1@9Tt7GnSkoepbxb99IJln4TkE43ELPjphUs@CdcPNK7YxR5uVsJynyYuc409YaGH8K8kVBMW47/Zi3G6aOQT13zytPh7Qo4MHxqPRoalVBIOp0ys7bqq0F/0zIt/N8K1sXc/vGoLGJcacFSADqUmZ@4h1HTdXvln4Zjyc@ZrgtSKOFvQLbKoVIQKiCatrh9DqlZ7bbRWsetA3IuhsvFqRFLzUqnfYaP7yfAYpQ56v@uR5DGi5z8MHhC/M36XxhK4bRBX2NqG3BPUqcoNesHxI9MH0ZHPIS1qoAfoYxA36O@6aW6hwikkb1wJY@kOmCW6QtfpKAolCiIiSeQqjVihguXU2IXwL2YHYunqiKUr7CxpI/mRDXIu3Ly//zOzI5leGrjYQyhzF@P8ZxkGUjGit3Ly2CE8XTLqmvPNCFJuqj4CEo/uf7V3ixC5ZF7SAkvC/MM/Nwddx0dd1mNoD5q8ksd/DI6JHZN4Alr7J38kBJnsSrBlJFL@Cz3wPu9QScTxJLsEnQQyP//jNE7t@E7i7OrFQpZgTJSx1O4D9ejhzoHae3S4/@gQL2Rsx4hGBk8W9Fjs5n2ZBFj3kiAiy1ZBzF9lcdbK4@nl5b3capaa/1efYvMZba6WLqetblpY7sdOuYout6CPaCgu3UPSP5HyfGkBtWPa0tpa7Zb0EAjQu/0xrle/Ax8EjC8m2OGznG08/dlk2pa6hTDjucTQv85mWZcxyZcJeNThANQqCsevVn4zM76cmUFXVjN8vavFveYxfmiFdvlJoF/2DHJuNuMvfE9PT4snGJ5qMvKKHR/dE/noGK40fALMQn9Al5roNhsmntcG2RadF07az4NPhXar/6Llo4LM7SmqRNe@8bUZ/00l3REPn/Q4FMer3hMrRbe9@Vm@nQdk@aP28/zJ6XFVMtgw2CiccCJyPyP9pefrT97wxEAMxnjPbrKOus/bgy5xu@mjLhxk6YA0t1BDzvRX@T702DBGXyLPxPupIqY5w4oUCh8NKAc@AlelrYu9aX3WcIpPTXFHm8XniJgLkbJCMOazHgeFDZhy/jQgqsnWp@Is3piQ4esDKoVoSEQz0zCORTjmTFkpfgNfqDANIWdOGlr@tGtUWvc3f4NxrOmJAXNiCB3eyZTqHzyuP270/c7pSiNXepJHR0cIfSRmjdSn5LOHP2Pvd190hwPfSep3/DEruJR1UvupzAaeK6z4In0V0riBahmFGy/oNNQOrFEmbtFb44wnZqqkjfOUnrfT9XTQx1yxulQGe9rTSgaShg9Plqm9jahhIcJ00yQdiS9OFyr9/gj9aWnYAvQ5OoDpz9CMEAM1uEtFYpiquVsrfC3jBOh29oEbaorOh6Goh7KsZs5l/O3qX33p6p/AuoivPU1Y3hRDSmPTDmy4HVku7BFzo2aNK9SgtNLqosu/9E6f3NNoxcFsdaWkTVOYDjZBgs5ag98WxxP8ktoXLRSkNUPZV81qvCx5XeguNZomwSs85euJIOV5A@EIIjHFOlJsahcDSZc3DnoWiyt2alVySpWcchGGniZUsiHFMJCn7bahgU7bWnAeAb4Ka/SSWKj81guMT8WuiFZKhmaw59As0BaGMKA4z9qNWOp1q9LWphVCgBMxguC4c9KadMdrqfCGVymYb2aP4q7UexR/k2nAewVMMNqCq6xUljGTTF4s8CrdI7eX8KmeSlfy5XyF/pX5fzqvE/X/SjSx7EJW3MRyPvTvd5LYwJ6NF4sq5Ru4Iaf@Fw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS                                                       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQ                       #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1

Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #e.0,1,_ _ye{--}besizeString xflos1''gem x=4721en nd ogola=1$0C0 cod/|puts_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;#6or [9]=x 3 8[]p#s4;93
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
wwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWWpppppp
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

*/
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0 "//"
char*x="24 10 31 1"
"a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302"
"h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000"
"o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080"
"A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000"
"H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA"
"r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF"
"HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc"
"IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc"
"JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o"
"IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye"
"K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e"
"HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je"
"JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab"
"K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
int f(char*a,char*b ){puts(a?"124":sizeof(0,u8)-5?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  "'\"")[9]?"75":'??-'&1? "79":"77");}main(){f(x,x=0);}//<*/
#1""/*/
 
>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+R++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [3]][1,:])[1]==2?158+4:17)#>say 27#>>say 170-3#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

VIP score ([Versatile Integer Printer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/the-versatile-integer-printer)): .001349 (to improve, next entry should be no more than 9548 bytes)

**Run the code snippet for a TIO link.**

Relevant code:

```
"[${ print(g+91) }$/]es";exit; ... #< ?>
```

`"${...}"` runs in both PHP and Perl. `print(g+91)` prints nothing in Perl, but `91` in PHP.

PHP considers everything after `?>` a string to be printed, even in a single-line comment, so there won't be any syntax errors.

The other characters are for Pyth, Thutu, Retina, Alphuck, Incident.

Didn't test RunR, Zilog Z80 and some image based languages, but I din't change their relevant parts.

Comment: Where does the `1` come from? Does the PHP follow the Python 3 path through the section just before that?

Comment: @Potato44 Yes. That complicated boolean expression evaluates to simply `true` in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

## 197. [CPY](https://github.com/vrsperanza/CPY), 9570 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJTFZmUiJLpQ8940Wv2@MHezw7GHvW7p7xLnYeDOxgsQ9reIAF1q/GwL/hm6fFYIH@B73nnIi88CJV1dfdXi9gSmTG5cSJiBMnTpw4ccmmYvd@85swftiRqY@7uukwR7Ud1ra0G9VKsY0xe6Zodj6bC4UQqmZ1h33VcOy1UJjJjGlGS2uDnznmtWpon1QLwrOMDSyzayl95vQUh6l2SxmoNjOHzmDoMLMzP1mOse2@eaUlMWVfM7oA5qjWwFIdil9h7MzQlX6zrUzF5KcyHFgQb7MtVf/c/@ywltnvK0bbBsgCY69My1YRvqXatonJVxkbbautKaRFAFUszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqAx0dcSUpu1YSsvRTANpkmEnB2cnR1MpZJm9Od3ZmQ7NspdJ02A7w9b1dFSOnVm2oivT@FdYbeiYe850eJ7VuqqhsGyqlMpORxbYhqXMJFlllqq0O5qupqBBWJL1VH2gWgxDWMe02B4USS9miplGzU@ZamHaoh85jbbE9FzOmapPNgOEN62eakAJM9ORshc5FZH1ItoaZaBYYxa1e6YFfGSxoa222a1ptYG5DH0cS0B6NvrEmoqtFlYQQc5DcG2YtwYwkWNC0zbHjsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZuD8XRoib3S9uexcy7DO8Km2YbWmIqT2ZECQZTNJOFz2cle0ILWhc7MrmwoWFtltqENBqrDI4FXVIuiITXTNeOad/Ajy2wPW9j5nJ4KeWOHRX6wQy1IVWUDISZS6GBh4iAOBiU4MftqsLw2M1RoIHugtrSO1uKMpY4c1bChyHaKaVCJW03XWVvVIYGPvZVgtonN6wc1daWXaqVCyJiYC@tf60xjrcGA8SioBRRpJ1NkKlKPfYJ4vWez0aDPbK0P0U7L7HRUlX1SBz1IHmqbIQaf1mCqWp5vSQUYQ3VJow5AICBpTKQ00Mml0K2lAGktW9DA0fpAWM2J2ExVbA0FKiSxVaNNVB14otZkygTLsxsNOjxUfWgRblu1qMsRXuielgooFa@Zo7eW5jjUa1iNHamKxU4tVY1Nit2JLCEzE3NwsCIpatT19cj24U4EGpenSCkDaEwrd/r6RUhhqQpbapThW5Gkcmj7YIvdLV2im0tZYICBFVVirPIDs9OXlyp8R3Iz3bXuQ4A1BFTRWdocOGklOYACJh0oYFpBJ7qSN9nUQA9kzNan2iLAchyqDa0Bwoe9SVDNWkPLwpHEJ6pyDZXWTaML9ITKWkMD6WGwQgaaoGXCQJBg6g1QDSQvtRHIBaTwaU@DRrOxSQIdi4@HRFAYEYGNBUXdfG1THxIcpLQd5GWgCiRFjHsd9oZ1FE3HJBCPqHipLdUe6g6mGRptbHkY79R2irnFoA5rAR/fQHYKIKUAYP1@oF9SoQAYGsKkqmLUj//0z9vdLuCptVog2wS7vmFts0Ujt0KFheGQIcOCQNWpWACXwNx5csjgRtG1NgkIxRiLLKgQlOutOdTbzIQMrVsNemlPuYGeDZ2r5aicyflgn2B95ZpLE41zLlS8rzShYSkDypuqnWTPNqGVWmooTDyT7A@dTpElB9ssYqe/jz5diz5dvFShcLFUbHkpne6WgeFSyxQEvshjnPOmNiEpbUexTa0dGoydnmlkWbLFpFbFHKhGNDKBI5KIWM1ILIVSLhora5VWqqMZ7WhkHXixChlHYuVWpXWhrdXLU8mDWQKaW0SD3VWNtmJSCEQOdYqbdB@keQoGhzdJ4QrEmXYDSY7RqUAwEmY67IYHhEnZQb40kUFADqVsXVUH0UxKjqGYQLi59caIeTWdwiEqvKbV45FwJB6sOmGAmk5UFDvrqWai2NIHPRy0gCiGPYCRwELebcFIjZLR1hzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEUnFI9/iIuiTvcpg@iYJSYPC70GRPVtuBjgxCAPqyY89IY928hQypTDjMgOgwMFOlC00DiXlFarwiPCcKmawSVzQAW1NlxWRTg06A3Q1kuuD5QN0APJflMICNd5KA7OkrY8DS4sOq32GY1oG@1AfxANpQS0WZA8JH5QMKZjKk/meDjo3adiaZzecn@9hMF3OsdC35HoT0p/SjPQkrH@xMKGhYR71lumJ0h0pX5ZoYU1otdeAIQQU1sR0QRdPjDQUmxeCZsnuhpWfTedMg4qoWfh4o5HnriaFQQekiFP0kqDMqU8RUBTRHC8SSPp7OHQBupjKXPiDIRAE@SA8UwdUAgMnUkdoaOiDVgIFve1qrBzyLpTO4XOSD0HT2EBTMHSR7suNljYWRq0@yoVTaC8JiPIgiiS06iwcGV0RVnQigxg8GPI5ZsftzEJteEWEgCISm0koKeO8LOPumYc5BCoT00CLIZAxvB9DETlChhIHLVbuos3paptdE0GY4EWgj//UcZ2CvwTihOb1hMwWckj61xnvOoYHMknasseaY3N3UzSaIZRv6Z9rNId0aNrXRVIUozGvDKzt0AwpYx2YVGLk/DoHropGODQKTwjcROBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2bRPEOCJWTsdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKo8um2UcpxM5JMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6T/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyNrkSpI9sXFp@BaR9dTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdlCJBLoy9oBQYVo/cX7iYR7E6NtsIR6VP2iCqXKyt5eoJ5UIWzyw@YyDqQLIBdBIfgCcSq1TQGYtJ1VuoaKrZmaz9Jkrnk5alDQQRXig3CvcLKuSIDFp/gNNISy3jIPs4TfoVC0ZBUFpbvagVubzIXNYv7y7b8cv7SAJTx8pKpQmVgvyi/VTXMocwXMYuVtaScj0Wu8jBINmsRDKR5Wi0mNQhIyUW@64Yiyuc2tGIClI7enkZAaIK@ly0ehbhGyWysZhHKigHDsygE0Yjqbsi5N@M1WPxCKSNRRIwxahEIkCZFhLBpkojZ04Q6PD4JSfMZjweIjY0rWv8zoh9CEvBBIsn3wH@3TyZnPb2r0G6spatoyqStLg2At70Mg9s08PTuNbYHmmsBgy3UAMYbdvezAhn48aQ9GdSbs1gRjQdRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOIO9oIJgjQ78euIoTjN@pCmzDhNHU1dU6qicSg4@C0V03N1YaO@LCSatk@D4DeA86BrrSgY0@iu5TYJSAEPk@n58fEyjOIp1UlmtV8qY4wsLQUA@nX1khrH2p2D8kLmhVOJawOUBVVdtANVKLaHmvBmN8FSqsjzeE6PPDRCSbZVexoDLXGGte6UNlDjQEL5doAaDg3WzDfUUFzwFg@eWTbxo1mmQYSObUNqIHhy9gGU8jnkRfYqFbby249TN95yIFiM8FygLZBrNPEbdktljZM3eyabBkAkDVTKc7YewaaSkDnc2B6yWztExGo1jWN8RQPqjjc26gjyoWcp30rCJkm@NQVyBo2v9I@wAN1Ptl7vw0jhJzPZKD8ri9DH6@SASzTdcTAFvMBhMlWR77BlnyvDnrjCYMS8gefRQI/mSrvmHxer8CACqUSPfwTJQ12ch4C/dyNaruueXXfJg0JTRnBWcZE7UEZhH4qqsO7DdQwPBWMoS4pJpDONLjfvjsgO097QzWktnomky5Bw8hWWbqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UiZcxLJkzIIcccglbXVnWtrzl7ZO7SDVRd/GHZjUWrnY/gSFOdkJhv@OIVTVK@rDW6HH57hAOSHVLpyQ4Ot7YbR7XT3YqUHtpWWteawMFttdEHxVNXbYlNf8LsWAVkIv2na/3YNJ0Kb65rnX3xE8Y0bvL9rcb@3sZx7fgdLwShsbX@UFewKGtLUwCY/ISi3V4VsAN2LLPvaeS2aIilHJJenbD54/RUxK5g7FBY/APhBQzvoxU/1Qp1Wy2WNLnXCxSAqwiIln0aw7rxOEKSpd8LFJBFQonW/pTVdANLGOjZ@Scs4D66efEPJxKY7@TMPSK3jaE9CNTsTpYp/MbpdHDU9oKzFHydRFbX/eAcBfN1gkkLvSDLTNRcYA/fCuHj6wtz8c1EzQX28OU5PlyXmI9uKmYeqIesQMhwHWMurqmIOYAeplXCFFz78OOKFPfQwofIa270g4k83CXCjYsjPipaKhFBLmCWc0efL1zYDbSR@jySlSdiMYovd7BkGyYn6wiC/PIZF0IgCLQ4e9BOOSPHR5ELokiCzsGXQbx4zgiy3lAa0Cv90rohgSiW1EGAyQU/cd5LbE4lNTU/2APn7ZrVGyAChoEu7YYEo7xEvAnd9ZZgp8jyFrTMwTjQl@@ynPh9TYiTQO/KcXKTHELtyJqI5NQeuGsuE3G8W/J1lsYVN9Y1xDILtgsXhKcw9O6boDDtazatfgYlY8hT7C9Dkjs7mVDDJT8m61sJWfJmvnlTCiIimQ1i9drESbHvamRSch6xeCj61/psyg7olvQzATpTqNkYPlb0mx36mQOwJixnMCziUhBS5QVa/9G4Z4Kmr94SGNkACBlQSzOU9DE90BowrzyTdo2JwjTVzhCU4DRM0tD9BbBkqUiQnWZTewgU6IJFd59zwKxhcx7ZoLf2ZkxfbILwztBydLUtnv/xZ21ogNnm6SljUvw9RwPoRrzRebC1RFL00M/8liWYq6GuKUQGcn0JZUvB1QZF9xzzUaMGw5LJnmL1Ub8WjQvMiT/Qux7hM15yS9WHbdV9zs@ESDxpYOOpDa1PNYInThBpOvxA8inzIE9PUyzdVNqEhU@ENNVvbd4u6ohPCQKaNsiiryina8Vj/rKZ0xs6Q/6LK2VfaldtgN/5VFmbZLJMXmnKatq0laamPsIHlnI9bJvJwXWXKo1FKzzE7bwTodEp2dGVa@5soHM@AXgVLa3bVS33@RDYbQ90e5qUpG/p8QiruJoVI11ZeQynpfPfh0DcvSqe42E6aTr9fAtDEou0oNcgaXE5PBkgkzZFWF1pjnFy1vt2zsIMSWUFwVNpxeOZHI6x3tqHv/A@GDycHgdmSl8qzU/NF@I5SeZNWdJ8AT7JDVNUZ7Ek/4VeDyOX1lf0ZLYdcD4oxF2jp@@aA0oz9WRLV2xgJkc0h3oDzUc/jzE4DkYtZCvf9Qh7@8Vxl8AeWk3x0wxAE9E1e8B7nPA8JE2n7dA@GtwRQT9@UvTN0rdNyrDdS3qu@QLBbDm4ovEAv32FgOOLCbhcE2CglPkQ7VrmLX4fVDF65o3Kf@cPep/mluorRFVSJ87QWnOSt1tfYldcE6ef@VS8nlsqp6XPDReW@8npwNcytK3ppg3zcvx9jBCgYds2/53PykGaaYqRJANz0D0/mSjUgKWEQe2BllT0rqkXit20Aj8PNvfQ6qD4F8@vFXue2JLlL4stVzsyDVk8H5T312nr@kucQFZoC1erAs5HBtt5skuscjxcQZhD4BL0/MrtZIqUMpXmRpKHGsBq9W6Vsfv8CUPKQ9R1h5TBmHRrUP4wQakIDsfi@vZPyW3l8dzaXyeQZtCufqkSgca91lUQz/Q706Qsm5G/MYWcyXy9eOroQ3WoztXyDptXKm5C5OZc3Lmg6DpfBj3dO/zGQmVENZaEOTENxENjogf1Scwcv6rUOHij71EBo@gadPIvqjhz5d0AFPIBTraPwHGEjtmEXWM4mGjcAO2Oh8bx45TrDdyebbYnCokx3yqRil9WpCZ0dlul70P6/XbfhPmx2QeFwfiK9hdIyfLBfycQU4ivZkwYSOZm7y1pg0ILige0qHZtJ9E2/nVCJ/vQpJ6ASyWYthmqM8bfhyg9T4g2TVP/lpYBWdrWaLOxnsTtpV9qoRklR@xuYL75wkZTSLPzkOGCjzNihgnUw9m088j8OWiOemRKOGNaf2S0ChjavzTJhJGaLEO21XLdDzHkMXZqOVVMrT7KjlwHNZuqrvDHqLDyGL5SKvcoPk/rEMotLczgYg5fvvHXv8JTomcwBmJpbZig9NS@St5HNHulfTW03ceDQCMTv3OiU2lajHgg3UCDvm7g78RSUUAbckwDplSOYnVVnJPouIYpQh@Sr@4ax1zi7vWVrsrPIjwmOnzTBG574zM53znfSLHGd6K0IBlfqH@cFaDjXKtj233ORfhq3IL2HPYfxTavj7fQAvrFTp1Kz13a@YK6Z/TMntFTexZ1Ds/3UPcAjnT4KZLHKgHl7yn2Ne7zI3nkz@V6dpC6uqnrX0NdlIdcOprmfOPsNu7Rb0PSb8I7VpoQIR5ftOPBkE1EorH7ob7TU4cwMtmmYw7UJPkeAtXR4sN/59ub9w4jNjvXVKvNNymg@U9xtKauslsNinBlB1fG51uTmrqp4FbSR5R3oIz7/Br7VMu0vmj86CqmMxjQozHQhzb9kJ032ZlvwFxjO1TSr2EGzeH7QzjLql2z2eppXypSU1UcQ7tOu4Yc7n10XiqEMdVcY8ktDE7pGtDKGqeQCSrB@BN87D00/gWWcebWfnNoWeMvC4bJVX/P3spXCdDxUP5igXZONA35uAHK3ejzyFKFWM99kJtIgUZlOalmQCuRH7T/TOz1EtKLFhYfUHqm6k2FCaylfYv9UmwIIEueFtjUAOHzjBcPCcJdId9gVhjdHXbt2JcZt9cGnQp/5iKsdfFYFV9NsnXzNmBthq6vGOIxd1T2Vh4fWxjJP7oykkqL9c6kOnzQtqVrA5v/smQnOxfL7AL@LNR4/kxXNE9b7fDfL2l1fdPCze6gPiRblmq30OSNkpdLRC5uDLMLEjipMx/YhZ1b/Nn9AvP0ksnRLfn2QO0quPltX8N9cLo9O@AB5umtA1@D@PVQsbXXQ9NR5@Kc3kLwNShfKV2ttTvRAi5Cl7pipxR/THQADJptiNueZtOeY9cxv9NwFqPV@NnIaau6d/btcSNIQCcSWz9Zco@5W0Q9B9r1MV6Zm9ekxikW4h8UcppDxlLxnFvP@dstHrMg3A77g6EtHvNz7@MJgqDNuH9N4fatBhIw@REELuspujPfrhwwnIIuJUZB3/mQhv1e080ue1/MMFC9QLihwv0AY23AmHykONADDHuexkczoWwqj4dpvzTOTS9loqUiyVUc@yOwhppjSc3QnMetMo6jwKzIfWIVueKFZ2bS@/ibevatGJKn8@m0/2ilYIAft3SY53wJ6ujdYxB8e8YxnQ/0TpLYCbEBEsI0Sxxjs1PuWdEwbRalcyXuOQMWxtMuQxwHHdNKMYKLRpV4PBYL8US4ktA1AMyFotN6eJKHHwS0ma7ZDsFqHXZxwZbuRmuZNfmeVZi0JrF6nWPFD50r2R4N6KjdMU9@saTUK0uRZDKyFLk01lgm4oGrOvSqueDKBGxHowcvr08CZih8SzC63RqX@Uklu0enAEF7bIMWemaQcQg1Wn7ehh/mOsUtDP/hr9ricCRMVW1Q32BUA4Lg2WCzr/bM26c8X5F7bTBQ8HAl4gAhqPOjPsnNGoPeCeoqPxNp3rKzndOiOGklDiKD54irM14peOOiwQT3STu88XhpvD2vImMvlVuplqkP@wZMENpOz06xE422QA8tfy8juBDMcCycJbUTbI@1VVwopp3tZBjQTfOajqhgSf7DX/HzZbS/Xew7drOnc6WBHHEbu0yHulotcwildpF8Ui1TgESRyCASh2hyY9gnKDyGu77p4BtwZNI99kXZ8LNfm7UTltxmETxjjadJylonulQ7fv7mIlOv/MD6afU//iwduxOEk75Llgq2lGAuSPkeGSsYnYdoPzbCpKWRxDP0Nv9rYvP/LW8PIJHCmQz3/7s8ZpoD0Wvo6C6dVPW4UVwhEUU3tbN7/qtPp36JYdVbOv9Fm24NHCrwOK1hQwcDb4xQ815XWYoOuWUoeeKwPGSIZ@gUcPFzwrQdHs8yYZKlEfvMeshkyRZu0QYfJ6SOx@f6lQ1351AuuL8rvaU2h7Sp4SabyuYqVJ2lRmW9Si5LbZt4jPXi@8tRNpO8HK1u19O2S9TLy9F3mexboLoJk9alJ2nsedsHW3dLqWrm82dbGTNJuo@U@X40EBNLd0d7R9snp7XTsxNohXtX/OyYVl/xZQ1yEW267pk6HRAGuliaan@D/PF8AB6NsiWFrePVF7FYKLifmEAFraWktMSdAdE0kfoLyeelt9VA/CyAkGkdjbkctQfDALYhMBtSDSs/HOAxZybSiqOaxGUaynjsQB5hcNffHFlKpJJYBYiVBGJ9JanYw5V9ysO@hmJfxPI42Z7OBUGKefldePG8inNJcP87qfcABsrfvt4cy@P1JphH6g2gXqibZqe2t392vD2ZDHiMniR1K6W82EjPhTP2NG5Ucs@m0pkjkRCtahWJSZSAe8VgRveaNFXnVoVqCeHY6vPExKFUfinkMyZQpoKXw9TLnBbRKJUAdZAyVmtqn39HGwWK6I7RAXR3vIqeENiRPNRuwVOSwBymizpS@HGrgVgFudyud0RCXMjriB1UfxJuj8Oq4RgNSjulemCo8kYdm8F/YFRyXdk6GzExnMl1lmRZ@OoqTFh7HmyszMcotsQJIS3xskteefGSCChT@0qhCS7tORNHGWCU1pUBnkgX0AcwqVxjH4cmnZtyhYmnX9zi9Enh96FQ07YUrA2dxzIcPF3ujluEb2/npILaGVfNSL4HeW5o4EAFQIHbSbZHMDMCZuuQrOf3HHCSm@JIvTtUkrXTFkdoPS3BZjeaTdZQbIQO6jg6SEqsjag4Xg1EJ@ZYTbdBJ2nD8M0v0iHlJEX7ovnm6KTBpDDwZMpTGRNMCiGsXZk9Yg1D6W0LhtUPPPESwRFmO4Azsr6YTALluprhXmWzhkZbsmatMcca4taCamQmiVuENXIle05fDwDOuWziUk3/@E//nF8wcemA@xfCPcpsgO@PhK8D7n/ixsgy@P6Z58uC74@57/s0NtnsqXqRvbCqPriJHPjymTRTJ5QJ7n0@VBevtbGl3@wdMZssy9iWfWUUaCaUMMhzmgH00vrAFDfUxgjOc/Cb0McTvXgDLAJ8BfyB6g1qNJSfatWjeLZ6LZ3GguMUOEV7kdURNyvTUeuPQ7xiBJSwdCFfWJHTUMjkjYuQzjt2cfMrRxiLrYFMDN1og8qHZguPNDDJbim6WimUOW@kl5Tvc9IHr6BLABviE4ULBmnwFISXAuKqIll0SYnLMUyKA1lEjqBMa5uc1UAbjJIDQGIYbLgHxkDdNAWpgI8NdeSQxjR2J0BNvEoKTWIqv2jGRZQERBw3XoQx3R397ay4@z/QQVPBZpDOEewEwdakecx68T27dC6NurgQhQHj/WoO6xrg/sdzbknhnIUnQGev54hOX66BtWHPTgwTtz3vQGlZNJvO5tJyIRbgUEmggvJiV/8MKKFzg7BoqdqVObBrm9t7Lw6PTmaumSDIyDRYhEWq6/HLZCpxUfccEa/ck0Td2EmfvNrYcUkZLJW/KQAh/J0B08Wcl9t0SR/I/ZzvI57NmyJmMpIzX4uYluGSO7RxZha7H5sOAG7y/YszuUZjd/cX9fXqpRGeyf7zvKt3wqllZC5wXdp08U5kuphYxD13d/QpXulnp9xTMlnJv1jKO9vD/X7wwxdFeBcE@rdFuPuwQ3SO0zvGGUo9sEMb6p5K86zoqgReMLe8IGvcospYVD/DVmhmY0ewNEzUZfYuQ3FQySPSIbchuTfR2RzSJuHMrUx0ZYtHMw/u1MWIXd@/v0FcXNCD0ulaM3Qrzti6x7y887Upe6BrTjQWMgTE9IGvWUj70WsQPDClcjFi3sklG3XGUYoMgVG6Zei2HuK3SDD3soc43RdxNAS6HZkD5lvRtlTXdQw6FdsaQhYtnJC9GPYBrkOPYxVHCxW0rCQkBnpG3KJc4A0JghKpfjsfHcVSPXXU1row4kRjCRBN38myf9OEglclgF7VnFcDNEsNegrUAZsmt44XNYxi6yXy@hXk9kR2Oz/YqIcAGSZtxta45SJyZriXAmHDr7FIwqNMM5aIpBifSYn7fmhxmgxRKbbZw618ZProdDRS2YLnt/lg3tGsfgprBcMMZ6HnuJE3yDXfdOlHgDLKhZLSjLY6iuL56rU60gnCI7fnN5GYNMPidPOIuGeiPX0FiSsLFUcIJf/6jil5Vyp5cm5SNJRKqZ4dwjNwMCmBHE8cax@coCJEO31lwKJDusPFZilG3uhl1EjYjhVjySoO17fMYPE42TTgQREwZ0HQDrk0OiwfxSvPoukKNBKG2kYbH5@0AbuQU6k6uCmTGFtCe@YmaFNoCYyFYI4KSdYILegX8LeGJeIXVKbERZVLlG2IrlEAqLnRJKe6PZIvQAuqNas@8c@sBwQMp2qptCZaY1LalxjwxfocgQho50hxd44A9BWnmIBqKKMBatNS2xrIy2cvVcNQgUDAM328j1MZApNZsYR7VWzCv8qNcgjzIu6KY1FQ0Mkr3rYjd7oJ6tpSukymsfI9qDUfLlGv6QjNZpz@b9OpdPkuuqRXxmnQNWPV6FKvIsdzy/H4krEcXTJQ23ryBC1q90ugzDVSMEEdAVBySY@VgZ9B@assGeUlZT261K5klykFeGGKfAcJfrDTqbsl5T699ASUpQSEWFzoRJdsun0lk0rJ91A@7CFL6QTwzB1eI0IXwGL2S1o8jmVILTWwAD@kL0/iNGxenqTJeFcWc4F0ty@625Qq5rXEzMW1nIAieM0bsPI4YIndbQ0X2L/gLTcv7gH1j2f8EvcAM9q6oNrByZc0GfP1gkXIaZS5QshE@fU3QMBRFIiI3oQSi4Ew@c1vwnKBMelpIRc140/zmXI8kpdhmg7z6/Az0MPTy5Il3V1uJW@YmoxcdJR86mP96Pro6G3sMspKLBLePJTkFel7Vsqyr/ussuwDH/bbfMLh5XQonF6Wn6ym0x8@fIAZB3wuqqkqiA/@iV0kI/WL6Cpj1dXV5UShuJx4FmkEChaLZrOxE5Zml5qmDex2G75mj25rjob55@lTygum//DPeJjIXzhcD4KI0PC3win5MLtcVZTl@Er2mVGGopXwk2MyOPG3CF@Z5fNsGz9/@7//7Z/97Z/Q35/R998r7Jp9gs91h@E/uT@1A24F3c3OJ7ydBqYWFZILg0gkn4ucfB9h/9k@i0yuPl39T39y@DHshKvZ9LkFTyf8MVwohrkTHODLub6bcDW8jmCF@/A4XalUwLn6n/5XSF99AXgwZrwOP9W8i6swDleTFUryOVwtgEPOZiHf//tnPwuFq6Pwp7Asy@Ex/TXCGRk/xSfyE8bAkZZWi5JpPnPLOwp83LC0LGcv/fYMNDc2rRfcg3ygXZkZngQlt8dVTHADOb4FDu8jLiw@@7DFmApDLX7W1p7NEHx/yn@cSsInJbrBCD3JkVuFcLGSaPDsPV4NBxxTFfZ@mai75/9GuFDYvVQzeaF06hNUvwzLxZXDZ6Ov/jC/0C4Rwz7tvMzZdJhLdc/D3E7PvgUuFP6hUjl28O9VE/@OTvCPjX7KB1A/hc8i/NE/fDwv/i5SiAgmkNnP4m/RXUPhi/BFvf66R38W/u0a@Nf8iH/7n/DvtYN/py38O36Nf6fv8Y/NVCYUXl9fD8fjx6AaCp79ms8ZfFOphvC5vIvofqcftnJYOHwWYuFkPZ68v79IfT@Kl8viH5SmsufDD3dBser3yeT699V4/IKKd1EV5VxP1qtQVl5k@vl@HRDH1y/W11ONarWarH9fvVifTCTSPXsWx376DBJW6xcXofAdtkUFf5bxp2Xjb1aS0uTFwQJG5xK4GDnpIQIY3aeP/lD4w/qHaPxp/GlGz9xk5Gv5@pV56P8fHo4gQhtlrkwr08v05DZIRJZRzzLjzHiU6ZuHchucKvxl@uDUMp1RppsxMoYsj0cTqB7@7x@azqtDE7CZkNIZZRxEnOnAs3t4@ArwdSDvK/jTMpnMCAo5ytzAf0ZHQU1XddHz@0bsMnTBpA8qjP4pOZLKRFKFSESr5wuDj5d399nCRykRaVxeROrlcNq@vExz7YhlV8p0Udv9faOxfbDVaKSRj9aX4s/iyWfwqVTj6@LxNFwtP71cS2L7cf5LNcLp9aeX1VwS3YU4NFIWwtbT8W/8@CjhWV28DMGE7/wcv@e3N7fcRQ5yXZ6fe7H4k8YgclEQfAA0PTf9hIOBpvl7@m8f/pf1/@qMRS/qMcaid/frUfrE8C8Wu7u/uxe/1Vg0KjzRdfjDAPBjkrv7KjoJ6A5cF9FYPXZ/z8PgNxpb5wirmMd6lRL7gNBhwzzXy0gZNLzKUlQsql1ejjKZWLkJIZ55XflM6zOxMu1cWWrimhrMBuTlGIHkV8rlFeFeLZbLReGWC4VyedmDyoBHOAFItZVWGRm9HI5hETj3RzNoU6HLMCPRttrBW9GfDgYwsZNLmc@fvaBGo61ZjQaG5z5/voSOFMF9K5VSHkIyxc@foQ9GYjDpOzDFimkJpnByOotOGZz59fXCSrVaWAF3oRiLlaUlvpkl2o2X5Nj9UlripYNpViQsouTiaoxC7yMYz8Lr7GkVGNfGD7u7DxMR2Uo@Fm2O1RhbKUSL8ZL4qyzG2Hq6uszE38VFLr6yvLr8rF73ByHs6@U7pSLfV@6UNZzp35db4kJJ3DqoPHmSK0HtipnyZajR2Kqd1hp4M78koSAdMIahJDZCuEQ4sCIXZJfJl@oXWPD6ZSSyVn7Gm6eYZ@FIWcAlIyCAWLFE9QvD5E/r4KbhEcpn8V2Tl7O5xXR@9F1hOwPK8udl/FxcXBSzxfgyCKjlUqler1Po50VKc9Efdep0Z1EleSEX8vUkaiFXo84yFFZezYWXQwPaELSaYW1cU7XQzrUIgT3FZk1c/rZVXXcv8bw1Lb19q7VVwH60X9vcPk1k1wFldqe2mcienG2EZfTmfT9F59B/vF3bOjyDBEf727WT7ed7b7bPjiDchrEOiAWf/pGiDtWGejsc3qK/odJnU7OVqytlMGgM4DPq/Pirn//4q//ux7/44x//4uc//sWf/fqXf/Zz@P4VfP@YP//435by@PvrX/6z//nHf/0XEPjv4fvv4Pt//PqX/@Jn/Ev@v4Hv/xkI@xvxDcDxL5ASsP3Rr3/5J3/561/@k38J338lvv9y@vvjn/5v/P//En/o/Isf//Rv8Ed4fv7HP/7hn/z4h3/w4x/@4sc//IeA/O//@lf4/yd//ff/7lf4/7/8m7//6//h7//ofyLHn3PH//Ov/i3//bs/@Pnf/eE//7s/@OUDvz9/9PeXXxH@y99DyNeX82vwfE29vjXklz@pPL8NNfxciMH@7B//@C/@EXDun3Lffw8@@PeifuF5vJg4zdCScT/wF4x9ToMOlHn22QMFlP8jhkIw@zyJjUIzbuivf/nP/xKDJ2D/URBDRp6FXUJgL7dfAOy/9goWhP3Fj7/62Y9/@Q9//NWf//irP0KBllwpJWqJpPwFWw4A5r8CDgELXwMHgPI6LmsvssVQFhyL62h7CMnxDx@ApIvgAl16OZTPgS8kV8ktoxsSwtRkmU@O4zjlh@8otFICH1oD4jCExHlUHKI24qxSqcRDowrEESh4Mc2IVYs4/0H1vwJ4MRFPk2gUQbVkow3CAikr8WPWWK6MeMI4BlQJA8MCYdCxJGeleLGyBRlWRlsMcSHyeOgDPD9UqsXKqIrofqAiAI74BmQJUBUs3aj6A/grhBPgQ6OtH6AoxUo8Xi1CSIWqSrklGpSnnKfKUd3jjOqN4YyhMezpM8a@k@SixKdhQEomoPE37kM/JWPEU4i/jC@L6tC/66TvMqaHdhoRfXgYj3@KwZReAADeZBK3QME3mcTSPIPoEUcVp2zhEecYgHJxYbXxAmiUjYfi1L5x8kD@UIav@6xXAx5Eh9VZWloC13pVykmHoM8z63rNdhQLVwhIpVljUqEkYTDuKFGXjkjjX95ahl8Z/rcXaVcoJ8dyaCmCQ3mEuXkk4zlzxQxT6d2qUV2WqeRxgguF/XCuZdIyD6iHKywWitKt1DGaNqoD0GBCr@zuhjkCVTAhSQm5UOLWUjGrfGeurVV@kFdWQ/Ak/xAvxBZXM0Mz4EuSUti7kKDVu@Q69TRwgrpRCFWrYqmKyaHqyfYpJDg9ZHI2k2KgP96trGZX8iv5bK5QyK9m5ZVCaaWQL@ZAQhUy@WxWLq2slIql1Xso0DPo54m15WZ@vfoPZj7/zT@Y95kfip9Q9S0bpdjR0evkfag6SibTWSpyRc6vlscVKAgFhaqkSXFVeXyXBKUTmyd0Sbui7nADDhQtdJdEVl2ADwsthNgCBMEHMKOhnonV473DslhGw9cN8KU0Sc4DM8RCl8AMHFtoMPUJYds9AYHzRObOfMF3ZtB5igdrDiALaAmD7eOORcdkpybfGbehtkLr4gBINRSiZYcLoGs9hNd5X9RD62kvdj6mzR5/CdemZYKW@tNhNhTjmkdtaXiRX8vxonYVvKnH7mtO7wGIs0EfT5So1u8Nw3a/CQVEqyMH2IAfSzfNeQCr7OzogVq@8g7q4fodndQD8OO957ungefpdm1zN1RgG4cHW1OPvADKs/3tnVPPu8pj3aR5D8W77f39aa944ExjkeVXEwkQkfCDzwR96Jla@t4FkVMPj52ZBGuM1aZ6wm@hH3V005Yjka7ah@ENOrCMb/bqmjpMopYymxlcUsApUEPN5sdsCQRhCaaBbD1fLYSlvFSsFDJZGGzoXvyOUcat8WF7pVzKyfHjqLwaW82U8i2rsjEsOo70dFGC@WV6vVoMvcLtXiWZH1vQ7NAuTGL6eEk4Hi53QpbahgnNrUEnMpr4Qp7hgD0YCA8MQqeldXsgHW9NDwDmlqGmojD4fusHcKjBj/N4gMPzoLCZGH0OOC5yaR2WCaXIdJUtFfPFUi5bTBRLxZU8zPfyCTmbkFeLq6VMQs7IRblQzJfkRHGllFsBWQqx@dJqKAzyRuuk0zBUyJJET81o4fWe63hPqpnqVUNhPvWH8RnfNhdWvIBhkUm54mUG0kkhLIZWWZTwdY4ZfFki4FNYi4V3djYzOzuStIEetNJtZiSpjZ58MZNZ3ZAklWI2QdpnJcnkaSAKwBzuyWQ2NiVpyBHgcURJ6qFnu4BqqSRp6Nms7exgPlfoyWJ6ALvmMdyju55VADPQk8uRXitJHz10AFfjGa1QSbfRg3lizA6P2YQ4SXrulieTAQzHHI5j2HXrWqtJ0h731GoY84IqnudFfYmeGn0kyQIPsKEkdcHRtWACLklNcCIzSlILXK2xAmF9cOHpRcNRJGnMCYQkkqQRQSutawl0MBGO2ezu7io9p612@Wds8WcLigYx2mi4vdN8/rzZ7TatcW37@THGvHixq1yNh1az2xTJmg34mJAGYq774@kPlHGv0VD0uTEvIcaYimmMGyqWraF8hDKJTxcz6TdeQMwLiJm39MGxwacPoE38bPThuaE0Kcb9UAw9R82mVEYWdcYDFS0ruPOavyus7AYh9/aVlmWW0QVa@2IkGkmML@R6mYJZPxq7y5TvMbYTpbc0oCiN3Y0vRpVMHZR0uYyyLrrYfyrJpby0tqg8jY7QXZDWQE1fkWJr@H4LsxNhkaT8dFiUCqvS2jI8padSDpzYvzKRDGPwE7tYrT@VVhGN9PRpUoJygBeAFEgKOMElrZakGC8QahNQPL7RSaMaOOVOdJQYVXiWTAPIdDq2jlID@zk8XYuxZy1mntk4dI6HDeigobsrhVRXey10ikoeveCN4XnbJr4Thc52wuyBH/qnN5iooPKVQqGq0HhO1ZGT2lVxh0grmTyf@KyvnwMcnhHFA34Hwz7bYLeUC273d3c8NyobgDJTNvCAuorepVF4FKq2FUeBuc/G3XBtTcDel7uVC0TwGX/Wk9J59Vyqs2C@@dUMlOrMaGVX19cvPtdB8YP2G4dh4MoWy6MwnehYXSlHYZ4Rq9jqR67@fdbRYLfYqGS4IrhkD/sXmcWCnLhLNpL3umI7S/Jqdu1iuHSRlOuLi5nP3XXpfVWqY/aoH9Jf0KoIAroMYW6jcJEe7mgfIJ6tJflLNeRiIZbCjecNs9Ogi/PZh4Dk9hMOyjCM6yroMnIpWxYgoYHggqjEovhGHL4DJhqJrGYjkVikDFCLECy4iLg4AkwXeYKsBuJ1TSplId5SnSGoN9AJ3GJ6JeBqcUEOhe9DbbwudaUUCt@F7u/u16uu9vCSjcdKPOl6nzDWjcMMKU3rHbhSskiuZKr6jNUqte5xrSxAa5s0j0mH2CU/V5VML37rqkp8vfo9f17iihpkE@LEoYXH9Hq8mq5Wq5chSZLCkmsTjxbzMPlBC8EPYbrsjm3edYYGHYJfe4XkUta4LnRRj/1woOl3xVyySop1FDrcfTi@nsbVulQ1TcRqHdJadihsmMKJplUHOkcU9P@8hDMtlQ1OSt@vfl/8/tXZ4dnhDnuWWSuuFTklaHPBs0RCjsgRoOwzGMO14@1QePDZzMs/GC/K4bVBJLcSyU3obZcVcao4inwQvcA1BPjWL2AWVY@Bq1LJPpUL2TXQucJVPNuYXQ1XySEXVsP1ME@8ArF1vqEsK4eraREsr8qxsJ3kPuDnfNiGxi@@@vAZZr/iXZ1allzptCjR0v36PfxX7y9ggnhP88R7@sefNPzccwD4R3DPwx/@JwAXhPHj6z8k1/n/Ov1sHvJCSwWgdvhDpQqN@n3j@0Y4FC5FqvF0BN87LXZAiGkXqlvLBv2p9jL@fe8HLIOGuOz5wLu@zPJVmTF1OZ1OX8ZeZ0EzK5UKxUI49JvZT3oZJonLCzUW4XfGcGFLL2B3j85EJl76hXP75YXk1snh5kuYQoO0VQ18@SHbPDxIYRS@n88/@9TSVcXSx@IFfWOEQiF9unmEr/A@2zqiNOd06o1CaQovclnaa6@J92MkbpicyrFsJpNPZ1bScp7JxbXM6lq2wBQQNzaecheuJUzKqFqb5mDMderoZowSL9QQBuP2NZgP2eoae360TynoAPzywtb2q0N2eLD/LuWG8vDT3b0TdnK4c3peO96GerzaPmFS7YTtnUjsfO909/DslNUO3jGIPq4dnO5tnyCCdAhFFY7vnGCecsvW7bGdxsHfJg13Itg2W9eqMxmuWAMljVcgTgYb@FIEFe8SnwwfGjCpbAeV55PaAkwzhy18bXHrWmm3rRAet9NabAHVkYVl1cI9qVIvY6@y/PDtp4yVX2StlYPIKmtlDozc@irTM@KP6Sv93DFbXFy8NCRPzger4enuwSDcqA1hfpn23m8vRAsrbBlU9uxKzI85ODxayLi@hfPj0wXZizveWsh6nr2dhZzn2QbfiufbOd9ayHu@jdrLhYKf7GBzYdXzbW1vLhQ9HzDpQsnHebC1IGdCLrFuTK29QC9@iu7s7W@zZQCKlSdi0aiCjqlgIER0aNj87gPSAJeXb3tmglS/5ngKuq1@CdoFn4BaQH3kAulaT7BlcwA/fbUPwJCM9k5z1dHqthICK14QAqNH6C60gBVawAoB/AKeukU4tlhh2RiD6IUOXyeO8uujEkw6s@ls3Xc2W0etoArMkKAbR@iMJaRQxXvaQgv3AmW0Q4anDm0cJVAZSipZUiyGB7MOzvb3eWYDyMK0ohJBMvJIc3CaA8AGVYRfrDqE8sbhzUJtgbRaEMoDvksudD/RmqHp1kRSQD0XFlqAYJK6N4qeYKhmJXDlEvGih2/4BmCIBncGXPxEWjTawrp2VadFBYohMbcPd3gNce2zwiZbOcYwU6IURfOt5J8/M9d36Ux6rUmvEeG4BXJeLI6Pl7SCsDEMW3CPAhIEHXumlAvIMfE4pIbqUFygXgtAdPjyU9JuKauQUSbCnjyhcqyDrxShLDBdnHJkSQRBBIJgRD5E5hVtkYobW0gv4wYD/iJmJCKOI/xGwubYu@EBJOt0Qada1euFXnMuGKrtlKcEsojqtLGtwZ3LNsCP4hE4OcGa0E0SzI2UCxiJM4oEUxOsA8FTMrWhGcC5quXLRJcVoDNS6x9s8Rbi15lQOA@gGoPcW6MGA2HxBLsvMfrCQtNSleuyCwXykKCAb5FpokgIDvd4uuMtSrbM@wuyJab@mpR7O2suH/HUwA6C04isOF/hvCKqS4FVH2gGv0CG/bcC6DlLcmTxuIDwuEyAbU/CJZMc7t7lyy9UYnu6FovfXAsUyw/WYvsrq/Hb1QKGNZ9FoBYg4qOANw7Q9DPZmtl5KGAsJBRUm5@GAgZQn5egj08g@Ir0MOT66ZPfnh4G6bXprgz9FlqQSwWeZNLbmvS2J73YfSFEYTAlyK6wz6yJLrkALjyJzIrgaHNZOZmwM@klg0OFqW6ajieBeQ7AcygqORgy4KwwRgmSsvH2dKWPb/CosNpOY@9g@3QyFvGl7IYoeA9fYk15xCbBRIEw3o6iJ@aVKNpBInB9M3rE80gQPRsnp8fbtVcJKF@Mrfs9YFoHgB/REyZqcO/mAKGG2oLxuJ1g0ZMaW46xJ1iyBBM2AfR8dRa6aauA6sEc28NBlrLKcBDPP9mTwtgjQ3OykqIsGmOfLy9hSM2sMrk/@Jzr54zVXJuNc6uo7HI8ng4ipLwrYA541@TKBkICeyp4l8bczK4yGbZi5Zij9kDjHmWsWfxUr3sc22hYdM9LDkyalNlleg86yhZxuwSMi5OqzeNaJI2NyAcYit0YwnA4J6tWnPRzZE@KdRUsXpa2@q1l@ZJGO1mWJC/LOmU6W4bfCMMeTJdCU2di6ZIOc@AMFDw2KiIPB2gzOcIgKxTitpTAXU1RE9@b4MTW6I4NlCmNBt6K12hEbVXv4MuUh1YLhnxUl20Bhh@MTfFI6kjomIwU5EH9aTKireExT7zOEEadKYT0TucK3QwXpRxDIa9ktqMOqFSBYqA5DF8qGswQJtgTfmhWPH4VKHFsTWjFOwr2BxfZxcT1OhzH0O4l5gSDeJ4N9dh0TpzHNnPi8Ba1eUncY8Fz4q6G/XklAMHwQIw42DcnxjAP5yXgt9P4EfWLAAEvggSu16Ox@U0P/WqyxQPXCxH9T62hKu7K2TsMsCAol4IDA20d3lKBaVsa3kY9jcg7Wgwpo6NY4JSzx1Yxn5MUu6Vp0@hdTAIRHdOjC5fZaA1fSz/6Ts4WY4kAwgBGvP6ur@gP4WQBpFDCOUjC/P3hzLVy2h5qZMFpvH76FB7SN9owvfMTmINH4DHWh8XGd4EX8H4lL8Zj5jldzke3Nss4FI5WeGx@eeImqoeg3UrIsSBBf9vsk9@afTKQP/bJn5R1hV1MlqMeD/jXIMCvo9vBf1JGbqknc4t9U42DXKOq1w@wL94YEsiG3xQwma2HRkggj6fcqhB6DPhKIYG4goi@Qb5Q84lzzPNS@@PPcoUlZS8Nl3h@byCzeqDwIbzjoNHAy0EbDboVrtFAy1KjIfEcaODFAS846IrOxuNSoKU2TIqNSklFSkjJZO1kc28vqRlSgl/yW5Fsx7TUBl7uJCXaMFGqSCSwGgjTU/VBRRL7uRSbUWrp4TxqgTyggl/OhIB4LvTO9@Ctn1/OrhWskvkVVTKnMvNvIvyK3I4pNzx0/VhOFr/Sy81ok26dwmu8LFVDQcOvLxZv5MXrGSZuBUCTvigCz9cmS5@NdzHwItGjgWGirfFSA3rvcYWRtU9ybymRZi4VEb0dTT2IwOdUzn3SEb3ghNGNVW1V6FlkHkpJ/m2FomApUdMAv7sKGr/kwR/QJm8uEeVNuLZJG82YU0X1BYs5wMpfSHixCTTAkTmAX@9yE3B715uAGy84wSBX1IEbbzfBFB3hEBedgIuuOoEnsLfk36zYV0Zaf4iGm@DxeaHJ@cXCIR9rQqM@RU5KP05RhEjpeEVtVOCNxaU1Capu07Uq01erIPy821Vi9dCskKW7gLGYAdVhHtK597XEEr@DRgooYiiabVEaSJuQmMSVEEorr9Vh8hngHVfEoPo8FWZyqycigpokvPT@eBW4naUyMb1AisDkgRfGT8CtTMEXiZFyH1vzVBC/xYJQXHGbU27ci/lgwYMYXEUtFnpkJvX/m3lSsEn@C50q/X8/KZqZ@vyepzKPTGG@ebbyO5wW/FeF/r8q9D9Bof@dafMPqOTTKGd7/JS6/kU1/NvVL5J5Yxg2rO4Nmt6yP0UP@x0pAqvfpAe4pb6QH9MFvjw@u2iywWH9J47Sod@kT9uF8x2zVqud9mXr@HmtW@vVjt@BfyOzHz@/WtnYut14vtGubW11X3Q3D9TXxdrK/uDl2@K7551PH1XQ3ncPX7z/pA9avdDb48HtuXp0m1OLdm04/Li3O3Z2N876myf5d6u3mW0939lQP27p9tar07cvT5/nT@K3H18cvfjUz/Tto05GKfVzu68KbzbH50Yof6OdtXf2tcP@SXv7LNvf39Le7cQ3M/snpddyZn/79n1u8zaez6T3Bi8Pnx@fXTW33@vHe/vv2psfTaXw8fp2sJdulzqbV8dvQoe51/Lux8PD7na29Hw3fbvVGbQz2V3dyl@9PT7aOHu323upbPd38melt1fjo0Lv9esb5yDeXTkvDF/ZK3Gj9vp19qXx/OZm@zjUVMxTK6eem6/lwe3tkVnqr6ovD3a7/deWbKQP82/iJ/3T263tDf3j6ih39u789e3Kybvhq9cv3h9mtJOT5rZSGDTb2ZOr05VQq5/bi9@cbZ8Vleft89f9m73d/Lut9KueelBrH@nXz7u7782To/29Ws4eGvL@5o3@7nnv6tX11uaebh5d60ZtJZ3XT9vvDg9DZy@05pa6@9Z@UbvqvUvnN65X3sXbg@enV5961y82Ts4Oi9nR0ThjbtrHzd3OaOu4kC2mW/rH408d85V89jpeuLl6kdXe1T45odyncb60r79T@8aLeKv7fvRRT8fPZHnz/d6nd@9Odm@sZs04@/hm5/jKetU2Du3DzPGLl6@a@nXRuRq8N05O5FbmuXr9Kp5RQqOzXRvaSD1V8qun/f3Xg9GW@fF4771d@BS/Ob/OqVvXx29qH48zzVtj8Naw9rX@ZqZ9qNTemM72cPS8Vbo5u97V9z8e2u9Cr7blfH7H7NgbnTcrpbfp5/HO9fO3G/LJKHNgHHdWCtbBm9fnmrbde3v26biV33kzKPYdo/v601l/O769P@p9UouZpn7y7toIneVPjo@yt8ZLre/s7B6/KjiHmf03R@3dsVx7rcq3xurmOL81sgq586231rvrXWOQfqd9HB5l1Jt4@93AWXmtNTutN1qr/zJ08qJ3dnD05nYvX7Ce9w1t46iYOdjf3TzotldejvdeDbf3m1ft53tv1beD08J1dnvjvLD19iTnnF6/dEqtm37uqBg/1ftO9yweejHsDVePzq2Pb0bvV2r9ppo71t@Z41W5v/likB29qW0ffupeHw3MA3knO06f7ZvXeubT6e2nXbtQG8eLozOnbzqn8igvvw7lbj8NnBeDF69PDjdeHL5/oaxo2rlydfKmncmdFdNaz8rtFQrP5e2dTv9jv6TKn7Ze5ZRcvxe396/T7c322Zvza/2q/7J/1QoVS3ZrY@/9UDG3m1k5826js51X9zf2T2X1rPvyZGXrIHP0tn109nF02t58Ozx7c6hltq9elPa7K2@P35Rerr4/tU@Vc/PtS@sgNCrmTFsulPK3uZNS8bBnneTOr0rO@5dXhQ39vCm/2Mv21R3NelscF68Hn3q33dsTNdPsPt/6qBx3tkGSnh1llPzw@mB0Esq9Oe3frA424u@uWy/fGrJePNdW06cfr0rXvd7L263Wynnt00cl//xKLZ3spJv6Tv55/Hjz9dFVd@v8U3GlndnYf6O8HW33nHeh17va1lXp/PpwNJZf75yM@7WMoedvTs7zN6fmxsn57kmx96ppdZq7Vz2QDf3x2dXt8GZXXe2Nbosve1dvlMz@2@KmYa8cZUIv1L1@@/j05dtavJNVS87N4buDwXnxfJR/VTTPS@ZhUXtZ6zwfvT7sbGdWB9r56ehsu5fe2NT6RZApR/qZtXn4evf9@YtBJpQ1ChufNs386sf4zehd4Tx9FN8fvmudZvvnlrX7VrN23t4cvX15UtuL7zXHz4@ulcN32/mTg81N@0V8Ryuo493crV3bzOkdM2T3N0YHI2tQyr2/3u/CSGC2S@3np7lzw67VOrd7xZPtWu253dx7oYxGzzurMEbgZ/v8jVkJ/YbfnBbil6bxh8JvZwj17W7THIG85GfDQnR8J0THd0L8wA7thOa7jH@TXg6dBrfT02swuYFn2ARljbVNVB5SbM@7iRRfRJBgfROSa@hqmQN6IlrH0ppDB322qcMv2avw9Bm9yEsdDXRTw3e84H3zOCe1VH7EDdSXVOjQYP0xzjcdtc83@Wv4mhZxcShdUc/fhkMXF4YWWi3mvu4sRddiei8/@wAKxMDoJuke1C5LJlsdXena4NDb5PoQOvHu6cYcdE1B4wdmIe83FDmTF1tTUV2lwp3i22UOnjPd5BfguzMOBZSJMd1MgUYqup1CxTel2tqNqo/pjQZqOxXiOz6/ahdkMAy3cE@G0eWNU3tDQd1QrakNoAOe0F1pTS8/w5tDni2nxRIrKkMNxWpqDr5ss8FfhNDgObp73gaTew/pVKhYoOWKEWo2dO1pQpxTGaFvKhVSjLaS4/ECR2SPqiGqqO5uw@XlAaGkfVeMewKYlwcP49b63d8V6gncbU2dwGsCrYZAK1qQnlmz/86mTY4eUDnEF@u33@6dNsRrL/gWQ@9gzCM7LgNULru@QZnXIFB@UfLZbZm4wwCKj2ZHfmswVPXG5Lws0b5H3B4JrY0zbH@3Jb1MGouO2Aa0G@Vipc53EGZo655LcC/NE84JTwKleuITdEFsqPB44CvT8Q2aHGS2voi4Y6kqAdBuTvcEyNRmv98x7z3QMk1dMa7RVeZbZWG@YLUCjUUX@gfqgaYsry5i/yTNEbDekNTbBusXVLK8ZiEAsSHWbeYzA7sz7bfHNLyFvazRPoZ5eLMuXTdbUT962d1yw@sWc3Pi8FNZHaIlsYM7a01rzDNC80y0XAYQ3KdDMkE13N2qgVpXfGogOtrUEygF8G3ZDcIj6KpfzgR7vLQ8q0ViB9oBNL@ofDMQQl14xarzrB6WhUDvWLAyE0l94rhbiMCZXmaOOQAidATHwTBGPMJ3p85Qhe/08riIcTpdZOrwz54GPWt84y52KBXNnihCYtiNcYY@VTiv0Aha9boOZuWzHjUU7uDGJtSIF5kGM3wMZ1o8PtFOAeQXGtJNZnGidnROLIghr0aC9IL2BEN74qA1@FZc1uE7uDitQ1MkWoeMPn/2Ogx4PW48ck8BAkt4r/ZFBuecyfuyIGjZ9bud0HNTjE8UT6rez@6lR@7uwgTcvB1oI1WPgsBs4Os8BgyCxJalwYA7CMLbvgTB2NhUdiGvFhejkOqC4NLFOnvCovL6enQ1GaWg74qxmNcZRfJsIHkgMQjpapVFs8vRnJt4BRMDytwkgpX5CLIcwcpyVHYRZAUCOQ8YuIpBSL5jRc61k4iLAcQe3vokDL4UZE7uy9m4XF9fL@Iez0DgVOLs/KIv5@JZSMxRL8QnYzhaHhEIr0/WCJDnsoFxJIBiJZ4DFDzr@GSEn@tUhJdpMM@V@tzB6XemvLjnNNzBh5LjuwlV66KI9UVO5ZvSBwzcA8cSgfh@qAG9JcoP4yy9jGwOOgJ1Scitp@KhqQR/S5gYtIB@5alRMXA4giBQDBARXDxagl09NtY1v32wQ@AOGfh4nRNMTrAiTENAooDEKEJiECFEA63baPUHHhwMxcUY3/HNBzDK5ABXnPH8ALQTqv1uTiTGOPlwhRvwibc00RjC6RuFBI39vQ18vNk@xh2zewfPoQkXsB4J5v@61VzkGL0qbioGf3OE5mhQBJBtfEIj6sqbajJ/DHTzF9hc5AJ@GjtPSLVDCMYTC@2Q@EJzGpopsHFSunykOkRHepGRB1CMlWGewW5VpuhIjjF/AWuRv@@IDr1RaiIVOLyEooBIIaTZ6XHt4GTn8PgVUe6oUds/2q0hZphgthSrzeiNHNhBDEPV@aDq0TOEwy9IaF4npem@PoLeq0yw/NVunHgA2KCYBoVOlwjry5l@Bp4Hz0tAEsWDBqWi0VYHc3Dj3lUPTFTGnoOQtyIvtRgKRZnmjYQ04M2OhK4craKkI1qaqm1EHGBsekOJYnB5knbxbcAsk17vRj0X9agu8YvF32eVy9JLbpGP7OEAV4fVthQkv9JqqTYdu/epDyhVvUOZCMkSIBSEzK@9Lz/42RRv7BU46B1/NOhmPL3XV3MnlUXQHjntfpKOG1CQOBZXR7pz1UpSi0TO/J27E6qjNqkyPpQZz@2K53YFuXGBy66mFTKtfnE1oYjNI4/mkueK68auZsbVE28rObVcBzq93cMbZsgWwqUONRg2E@4XsszxhKx74jbZE7cX@z1xvnL3uFImCDupkYkBxx8/xYS53QayRWdsG3RyhWZfQwvbn3sM9RY9NFLyg07uFIPgiVMaoE67cK74xDNUD3IGYgJpSKdlLkR2dRpUPHxRgZAl3fLEAroGncIUVgHNAGnhH04TdSVV0rTFRDEQiGJVjMJW2@3kBOkPZlZ7@kAXAmEoP3Don0rgx/h4RkV00vsBK4QaOcTXWSmC66rJJCSIcbsG6TQgbrEOVDzNmV@N4mw1ROVcnUzjJ2BQ1Am3zEUBgn6GeQ@EupmX59Y7UA/3MBwmjgUqlimLExTuid6zI5aTc7nA8d/D8wNWKPing/G6K7aSzfhHjvHiK1YohX6Sncy3J3B@xI4jGhTZCnkGp@6gC6q6Dp2YP9oaDv1YNj4tHvHHuOwpV8t8BmsLcSyGBpv18c3jTRXfsI3rtQ6TR3IqtABC8TTw7nZ38AbA7lCxFMNR@RlLFORiZRczpISow6qWzd/rTm82B4mPL96GYcFSuQEYQtpmizZJIg5KBy097NNupAQqDDeqhdcAaI446L9AMkewAxcNVc4EbqArHKoub3ASCpFAPRqNLJyMNCwj9bjpRbiypK6c7meolKf7Mg1p7ltQsQBEXsEqRGPuDi0IAs8MMzQfXxavgnK7pAfsi/55psHZQYZPTt15uEDDx5jZmb9Wn2OMIe5qBcegkdjERKioTvWYewaOJIB7BKrl2iE4ED1GdRqeCBefjSIF8b3oGreFM5IRpEXQKEVDioVch7t0xJVmFL3gvQea@LkCvS8mdgaMxYE573ikgECWj3EIcTZyGgL7J4cYBXFAKXhHXU77@w9GiMM774bimzjEnYWjOybmBYiAz2tJ7eLl52fS5tdC9FHKlB9Jmy4pRcUCfXk@GK@yAMPaBcCgUCSP3Eq5YGdH/rk3F5BKTwapxwo/kdvXFl5kNwM0QYmvLLpHiHthq5uHFBL3zRuVL1KJbTVCzQy0D1eSoBEFIxDPUr8XpgpBA1cq8NI1Aym4zuymcSUJxYhDv7MiR0B5juWsexzYFeiemdM/1zuvopyT3aq61aQWpHcx69qAhsbJuopuEaxrUp6t7Gqgsu4p44nKikRuPWfvdzDA0dHNW37/Ag4okji5LH3XTrDv2rgYIkKCY5RLjXnyb/Ksc6BDfl/xe6RXP6@sdGjW8/C@KtYOUbQH@R3TId6M28nxZbw0BMgIbhpld3M9T7WwINQZUHom0mVjwuzssbOLotMBeU1b9fGC0/2si8nnGMJSYT9wPDQEfVKtCWAX7DPJeSxAzIPFF5IHYQNcJCTzRCd1uQMj4nExnlUmrMH@AeoHGTGIRcjOwBHlR9OTTJktxRjj@DA5H4ebRAz3fv8vBwsyfrAgSA5aIxJjnbdmxK9EuP9tV0Z93W0gNDfQuwZZ@PkoFDGhv@Uzrh4QHfj6gjc74POBoG4gFG1XGUTDFijwMDfmR6MTDHJ/EN6/YeQjX@DDo3mQkm4ACSajqyaCAomXMBuYFg0Ck5jZYlLrEEUHvE0my00NSYYQDzuvxpPBBSJLZ5O4DMidcXmmVhPoGB1yJmtcmV/@Qaos3k9N89Tg7R/Y8MtYeVyy9OdZAzwc7O52IBRaf6Cr/OSOvN@oHe55V1sx8fZy1TYxyE6ZVjd9q11raQ4YOhHXViXVIfZzvKSKxzS2z2AowwunnBQ7UflmBdR7US37QNNJdRj7gInwBiwDgDsd0HiNFr7dXnVucf@AQGCngoWFaMUGPdw02Ng0m37pFXEyhxcgQWW3ofBdIMywSa9abymOrY7VNCZMN3X46St4zXAapuRprGH60FD3IfUJdAk1daXcKKGtQMHo5PRUrnTVXCiJtiOKcfDlzbR7BG0IDr3AvGlC23j7U8UkgW5QNA19zAy8AqCr4FvEGb1PFrJCzruFatKOW7GoQ1seVJpHrGRKBRL2thjhKB2O36kUxOVjIf7i0TU832GbyC6WSntTKfnEnpapPRm8Y05uouDz/MmwFl7O9eV9Gt4Wj3Q6kNY0vmbfx7w9HnT/F5D9oZ0f6TSaRwe6MmbSrUIXPLPNldVMYQ3nWlrXIDbE3oKX6AQ0dnU0wNd34sYAHMfdtLp6o@osh834RrOHAHjiDKFKofDAUrp9xQWM5tYYZhO4o4vm1xMn@v0o09QnQzp4boL5M2o8mcaY7GOjE1xiVEFiimAxLqgxkFrw8xS3PJvmgK2Bo602h10aDPBclpsCT0cpiSYmUGLVaDP2FJ5r8ISiY5GWoR9j569491fhfiJTYxfQzevMXaCQyiGqBXT9Ci992U2PIweCBVZ0YMDmqxowIiyzhpiMcisBQOMYFuVwNrd70uK5C9I29w7RakMZ8s3FbgxWcSAudHxwT8kyC@wpAZGA900hY9IVWOm0axmJ1PBFrK5nI8JjyWoU5W7fRMRHvWWPHO7@hQ7ffbJOd4IxuquTyBkru7vq5TK7dwFxDwhqOLizJBlxdw6ghmnh2oy/IwVIL7mzsMfQBgqQ@wIkNRyyGY5LgWrwDd51bu0SKsh0tFx317AgvJIpu9Tg72322t9fzHrCW3OBKr5Ib4G@Y0Kdllp8IYZWScQC00RZcfASPELcwXGJIT7K@YECJrlBWBPJaJrwDKq8oNzmCsICdc4kDSkJNmJdtL7z6VOCjYUXryUP8VuHM4lxRS579xSrxrB/h5ORBE8yHCQQ@J6pIO3LIfwVMzqLZ@71bhglSKyjIA@RoMCgCzccTRt3mQST78uUc4te9MRFPOgRs7w/dy/WpYH41i5gKkL/dT5MrH3XlhI8P1wyIIfsOrL1hJ8bJ6JX6tHYvI6OEmMQHQzPI1XFrAPdwjhP3nEgiu4oEes0QsCgHbah4LpjA2kXdW8gY41RZYQ32FfQhsfv/0KFl3cLukAG4dcYACaTCAgzVOYquxRPZAbRN4rHMR4mdZPxw8EazrLd9DPx2HqEn6cP4r/3L8kjOjRGicY45u5LgRSN8TKRwNuecj9TXSreb1HfmfJO1XeGHl59H6CHV99Zev6k@noW47dUERhi6IFzHJyyP4UZNb733Q3kdoqnDAMz/gi19W469XCAL6SZSk2vC5hNbQ4Gpo23Ms8vAc9zTiEoPhAOeT7leayBGybIaW4@kosZ6Hp4/7sd4l3cMlFfjJIbX77Hxy/QJ3Vu2xZjNAUg5hJZ9D1vcsoPGcTEUBIMckWiVz/MistUrk6A2nZN@4srLJBV2Ss4VZTPwRgl9mofY9wbwBGoOm1fhNK4SZBQMTYvyRD1Dkw3nQTD5icRVBfycTIVUp3NTeU2IqYWuytdTYjEjrTHZ0m@1i0F1poaJJ2BXQP6hDeP9ey9o7jL4LwxyNIbibujNEzF9jpkbdvkG7HZkbBO4bEnUOGdnmUOuz2GF0WhDoiwfEt5x0TtHrVL0OrxhY5DvKtmzd0WF/Wr79mP0@xswGCST@fnsee@OmKbqPg3x2hL5raAaGCYEDusFhZc3WnBN2kvkKT3gOvc0MctDn721GaBAmwhP0ARXqElDrI/Jnaak7E7iCVlTwORFMdR@wMHNWuNVwGr7ycb4DKMnxA1APeOL1JWFjzQ@YXlbBwoLZUuWNx9YJV5pc3MLSQdQ50uZFNFU1/mkcJxK@K07QaKg7ljabbU30P7ebny1WuY93@BNSFTlysTBKfCJBc3R4Oyg0fz@vgiUbxZg3MqzMAB5YFp4dxwnJiL@RbtcdS7lFuYe9FUGeHiKVGcHsxnb3Cj0dzUtOLWU6Cp6OgAIoISkGrF185wvQxf/oWpX9F01EvMJ8A2qXJ47ywvhtnCVWY38SwlLLOlqm0bVVYFeYXKGcXjDaK7uquEbU3p4gwRZuqu6HWLQ/Zomi32tBY/lbF5hEWx1I9DzeKTbSxNCtqS9v0AK2z21NY1weKbbHzsSc1IAtkMJ2l2mP1xqFhocjAtFo/YISHj@UhzLHbiTOtRQkCVJ4CJ8yqzSkgAGNVPvApyiq1cex2aalyZR5t18EUREVu8BELYjOjlsQHbD1pNUgzklWeQgeFZFyd0NZvwBKbfCdYZ6iiLzUEK41ASTlY26EPFsrlY4ZcYTlQz4JkA4oJ1MjaAUWxDsTwMURrGxUjMJc2XwUsz0JjVA8BJDu3NsQL09YgGpJyg28TyDh0K8u0XEE328yjym@3CdHCvhaWKKQSmycQSlMksWhqKZ7EappEMYuZgs4gBDsFiX9t@lf9M7cdQATJQ9oCAwePvaGFsKWispKKL2Sf0dKolMrKoCsiB/lB3FEM1h7Y@/n0zQmiB3ukodGcIGpP3nfBOquM4DeOzszS@DIDtpQ9puxvuTcCJOgjv7P4axkinQtRgw/VNMc4yXRyDsRPuG2JwmSh6inH7Ig4HR3dPwFQMXpmAlh7cJuDQGa8E3zYAopOOixlOitK5G@yUljMkIdozcXMF7ikdoj0I93hYeESMmgQFNtYFkZsD1eKZAbeNzSFzx2fgV/@qTxCQ/l2bGmQqhj7Cj7IZq4V8zwcSwIO4A6hwy2FXDaQB8QsFB3CyHUG53eGtqQobBQ5ufHUL39iIOVC28ETcGj8D52f4k3Pjq3Bo88UsEfdUugxeKwCdLWAl4/vso4tifh9zJ/pT@59IZXZtXS4sZyixtx9XEmhXxaxZzp3AamXaaBHVKrhTYx1PWEC/BNALrb5YwbUWvmuDbGfYirfAIKpitXpQJWgvDRnGsYhOba1NZIM5HJq9vavMbQboK5grV6CNYb@JV9Lwt0R5xzRp3QON5AAS9VHHKGf/6KVGEk6LAz9f4lZPsh@3Y17f4lnRvAQnPwDo2ZFwBBVlIvulIAz6/Z1NHnU6UeFFU0gWyYL@CxGI15SI@@hnorJ19@Z6b8qXLU9jlB/BGPONZ1NHwtDg5QS2ON2a1jVfOUKzG0l@R9HI7o1rgXzDMiZyLXq4yG/7cXwlwzXO@a81of6MA0tPcb5s5HW5yQGhqPMDPfzglE9gvoZX9jcte7uRM5y3QIS1uAUqLaJwZxRPy1cuuWD3mMddc@U2RH42KBM8uiVoXQl2Bd7WwpTJz7VZekdoVxO8ISAFRyC0W3I0vwuTpJtHktAQFC88n@NQ4eMVF6wsjjslgyH3OP3n5XTJJ3hFNaoZtzdy/qhUOHf4eXibhFuBrbrL7vEGvp9sgvz0ctWK9wKHn0Y3khjcnFpmI7G/i05ajfgOr4Wp@TfjNb5AlXRhYfwt1CFaeNvEfZu8RNwsugHNO7zNgFnOG1OzPFcwdnjXn3NURWzy5K87gOGd4csUxPEN8AaN4bYT85brRQe1nZTtEO8ERvoklz7A3/P6naLbprjKjAZWnsim9cJvW4lxeyDPXvS75rCDRcGVfkjjH1CZPZ2y2PFEDm3N5Qv@nFIETvsOh4iD9/9YYLege6E@P7UCUHRkRazwi4QXrk0c0Ytt1B1hI@M1YMsNka2og3uFEVbi/23v2ZbbSK57Fr6iNdQuBsQdom4Eh0tJpFZMJJEhqV27IC4WlwE5EgjAmIEILIWtOPdUUqlyvLFjx5dKYjup5DVJ2XFV8pD39T/4C/wHzrl09/QMZkhKu15XUkuVSKD79Onb6e5zus@FHrwNdzYkVb07do/gz56HLer6WeSX9Mt3KbPJl4m7O9tPDrb2mntb723t7W9RSVLk1wbFk1GZbsr8U3TuPZB4s37EIU7m/bEH5zieOBRnCSXw/c4wCMQDEHddEMdftKBka@JmUt/ca4/S85767niVyx8wM0/G96Rp7HtoIjRBVSXo3ykL4Pw8bPs5Jn44A8khFWq99tGTAceFyuCeCZs55@D@iSupPaTosgQhLRvwSBn2glPkAKU0EX1jhpOm34XV7Jakjq2CxiuH0F@CdoiADADko9btrESRrM21CgPvAs@JbCS2lQPNgux9vyJ2udpNqlZscr@Qh2z1h4OjjPSeYLSAODc4tAoYJ3tVDTEZBUEVqLeAngJxpLlH3KEyygflaqlS/vxcGoSP2L8lbwVvYJL/hnbei3b6ifGTksz2VQwAg8eZx2zoImGTEi3okqM1RQ3qYhXVZEVvZk6ebk0u0V//LVuQpxiQy9atfDFG45@vPfelzaw/s4@FL94MJ5GAI1Y5inwTVUznn5/Bzv8Vq5HXMxe5yIriS9OJZNMJGVDtdYwnsstZ0j5GzmN7hy/s8apJX//4SrtbhjOK8WRq14oo2uoINlGl@TAejdREvpwSfUSDPqJW/htTh0/va4ItQNjdZLXj1@i1YRwR6WjltTThdaCeC1TcTW39eaT9ql5TbR9V2scz5D3DizRcc7K5URVp2m1evRIRNXC2dGEdXyJ/qWGuzVuUU3njMk4po8uzQ92ZccmY@jtfCiaU1kHeAhkji8NrRUPMSWo1bRIlXKUeUYiXclRO4Zovjl9MbT0cwfCylJyImZf4sq32Mo4NBqKiswFtD3LxOYqgDC9j01BGp0bNRVplcqEt2IToF/j/L9ZWmgTZwONLI6vfopHVl1YjX1qNfGk1cp7VyNLV8sQfl9veoAysWV8UT4H7zyzBgtrcEe8/vHsgDh5uiQdP7/@u@OrOU/H@3SeQsiN2n957tH1fwP@tJ/tbggron/fcMarcC5j6Tbfj0u18rVJZEYR5IUD5ithvnYiHw477EohnzW@dbBzzl9LADda51NZLdzwb8nPQCJVZAmk1QXdF/NakbpzQ4roNlHyC74jKlye2kbx5@nyzRLYXFA5dG3Dz2x7xIKTHRc9K2mgD4IeQCmha/CRLutP4tE5MS7ck5MDpn9ceQWAKH@@Lu082MdLn5vbB9s6TffFgZw@@7n4V3eyIzW10G3PvKWYR4OOdze0H2/fvUgI3oFISeLdGBuvnNaGE4DQqnRe9CYYH66NUKL9FvHovZTKDobKK8EV2Mgjd93SBpPDdnZ2d1slFu33t7t677yFX435NWBYGuTQcqksLhGsVNBqB2mQU7To7U0fWsljlDelkJq5hdj1Dd0D0uSAU8hy9E3uusO7jNSI@SFPcbGbYFGqo6CrgRlTKEawjKAJDNltYI5TrUBvdHqja8GK1p75g0Q3pmBXlyCXlpdUnpBiccXvQ4TC6KgHonrW6qdpgzAB4ISQTGADvYDAhaL1wt/GSRNyQEJMABX9IuMkJz09GD06Ra0QDV5lwjwOB3JZt4nmjKcUARy1vwPMYMWvi3YFipFARn@DRSU6/r65cSSUO@H/5xoavsgBpwS7Yg5WthIrw2Q2oAfb241Yv8IXt5PA2GEQQd@CxptZRvwXiHt0Lj9Fg6SWqEVC1tx38WVeO6hXDSYE4lQjTnoloO3S5TXnwu5ctByXvLdSIenvUaVSYkvGfLmzAvYUGvAkaQFQ09wt0KzQKiLElNMOeJGXbHwJFgsgnPo5GNRp2Jx03UkDKOvZz76OPcnKQC2ERQ8WHWqc17DDUAz6EnKIPKnJzAUIMaUoe42sUz6Ed7UH4NnyCyhBjbOCHanBlbabwoGqUmjiyUuTnU2ptt8gY7sJaieJZN1hvXyPtM4qev302y6NnkjaKyVqa89GfMyoxoGenMbp56QlULJoF1BIO7pAJ946PhV9ufHDbWd@896z48YeFw3L5iLeFVpcfL1gpkZ9ZSCSH5aF1J0kbUK00iTTjT9pYWukz8m6Jq1whA8bl2APme6NZ13l8rbqYPqB4WdF0Snz1yuFSRbI3IRLCSDLh7lYQDVVlgcocipxEEO6d0Fj0rKtSCoRT79cbGNceZ6EOIzLAfYTUa8ywaqRfY3i7xgc92Fkykk/j6db4cyoWuaQo@rHN@Sh/YN9z8uu5soKixaSH01ZbdEFhruZkr@Y4vXReLaDbPB8d7N@XR3f73Nbx8fBa2DbPxfZabSvm03HxsWTgujzaj89By4fbG6GFvhfSEfMhuYhNU7omzsK1JUXzF9T44cLc0doDNHj2YkRVjdSobTLoo4c4my/FoWlUIGeiCRmi/YPNrb09YW3hLdsqlIV9rzXokH0pboOI@6rydMR2yLTZlTTTpMMEaeZJpczZvDRa7XmLOXHwUrYKyYMU5HjozUJH7QXJZCqtI/hkIRYCDa95Q1QjF23dmdqD/IZEPG@gJpQIJ83oYCaxm0t8@LCTfdpkwnErMG/sv/BGmplxp9JZF11Vj2cmIsUI43HQOsKX7@T5e5/541VVDzNY7tcm1GFUwu@gv3yxDxWP8KW4FJ3Bc6ZFTSnprBCVLqmxI7O8KIf92QlKx2KfS17Y2NYlcyybxvzxNSOSHfGnG/jOP5OZnRN536m2eEpZMyc0Fx56dvQIAiYTxGCxYVIFFD@cyyOMRkOfk45myM21do1a01CtpGhmEnc9Hegt4OBv3IxvD/GqYLc9t6ri51MVnxKRmoy4W4s1qEzAfPPGjesX4Y73QhUvflbcfIbE98/gZPSyZaD0Zz6pCgHlbj8pqPyQAM4ZOgekwK6tFkysILA6CWdKpO90GJntg7acjtEWDxqz8/SggPdF8VpzYhprWzJ2PpFM7ASy0AdjCeuO8qpZGP35@dXdo6BuF9R39fXr48WGQHgfPv81h8ncG45wqwRGfNxkr6ggkq/6qBUXYAkOPqg9/RoxMDdUHMsGx5vb4BdutJHmGjeC4QvU61eRM2VsMwufoUonrdHZK7zgekVXppyHNgGyrFcQG89ZR4Uja250h6RE0NOhLDe4ldE02OZfNs3gm6uoPkh5DGA8YDp6ALNvZwXIPat4q6BCTWbznAb8iU4qchLQaoCyh05f5nS0S/BG/ZlOL3N618XAczp1TWI5bemIl9l1CRmPkJm1JDDd1Xq9WZOGXWe/w9nAxuikt2RjQLbsD3XqVU5FnSqV1JBlJ2HSISeBJKWTliQUHkxeYNKS77ovmjTJMtocIMwWxMDrH5ak/tQ7tpQdc9KEI@CJhPLuoJuhSaGYpxqVOhI20LWsJKHGhndYIgVKuQGhTBZOLC@kDS8sYAJDuhH6komKi1ED8LdshGyqSbxYc2PjOVL42PU7E1dsTVHGV7ERFVWSY5AlsfVkU@w8EHs7u1tR1NjiJvIoVEop7FEoZtkw6o5asgWY8OEkOG5yovoazz11OVeh4O8aaDAcG0D8NZ6rKiAUh7gsxdmr7ivRgMN7pCfF7uYO5aSrHus@lDrDySA4ezV9RdM7BU6vBCTwjpiX8JLgnYVhkStRctiKHOgtDsNCIl/ZVG4VwloohWqZSt8cQ2lxHVvzubnEltH7J0wdrEzapMOAnLBN4k4wRJZnVca3hOHoHIcBN@kt2xG2HW8YHkql0kJyXtzSgRtdM@JutLJLVpJPq@ROWAlTmMZT8jGOaFhbTnSH4pX3SlUWHip49N@OSzt6tNF3s5xG44ihZReBqRwa2fwqYfS5m4l@WlhwcgZFNN6ofN3gBYFB3sPd3GEaj4ARfS@A6c1BgfECWoCjVRAB5GWyAEjlFzE2k1sZLr2EIsktDtfjYnNSagnRJRRJriVsdHQqwrUem43OELgzDkiCH5ogCBrna@LMAdksVJy2WEW8oCRFEmeaXKfNf3IJdahtmiGAHg/Vx@ohm96IrFnsXPjoiJgtkJ03BgT3IHKngseamV6Np5tHklg3ischjEbFgAFn7KS6eC7Yk0gk6RQttXhZkdGWjAaOvJY8GmHLOTRAiYRSQItRUF41ISyAIghxcXiyGKC8EqOg@WRQg/gJ3sQaa6uxGjVoPhnUWB8LWItJWKOg@Tjowr5GG2V07DVDu2yfP3m5FD7WRGdU5U7dziTgk0Y5rYA1FMDyMBktCd31jrzgHREyWvSpBO1Bol25LT1iqzQQ8G/c0qwPFVCsttkEWW2IEHcLg5fyEirm6yiTfQsZc808RuA5xDW@jxugDYIwp0GwBybZEMVkSIFGnWKKFTOHhktNA1EnYyRhiaUz@DpH7rexdMbiDkd@twpWbm5xs@qRXRT6pJKlfLS2psaiFAybnkj8qcvGE47hSERxlMKkc34iOCaBTsUrjkJ/2OHLzgLiqithrQHpKIDTw04MB76mLPZFFQQ0hxe3Ax9UFnFgE/LivE6ZOJRQtYhj@dI4lMC2iKN4@XaQPJXUl7cujYMFwSQc5UvjQApcHFNr6QwQzPm3lURqkfFAsyiZ2iq0o6ShcbYi39rxvihRVaC9IGGIwE9j35LaIRlzk9b7hhh0qfFAoWNxPGyPV9I6HMW0c1f4grmKJXML64WFW0rlG1hj5dXFNT/owkFQ6vX1@k5Y/DERPXZJIhHSvQcKMaXO8RhEJJzNkpQ@FANCOKH9zSaqZjWbdDO0u7fz7t7dx80ndx@jELXEexRe36C2DKnrVEo1jGfPty1N0ilyBKpaYDcytA8bedQ@iWaLThGKHIulls4MuLnFDBTW5NB9UWngnooHkEVB6xdwImRJ383A9NjUBr2pW8WXVi6ENE8w1Sspr61DSwiG6US2hGCM5IwhbHH5ZwPWUHk2eBYwYFs02CbTPzTb@wwNl4yCQhRfPgvec8dt1CUpaqelPIuogo@yGzmnQpULeYMeYjAm8NflsrinnOJK@7VWv4Mubyc9cnx74vVbJ@1uqzQ6HmV6viPd09jZno9OLjOoTLV9sLW339zFOF1b98lyAn/qlHew/Xhr5@kB5uxD1nWZvLW3t7PXJAX1vae7B@gxNJZkmYASSwgmEyJAT3Ye3n1kwPB3SzaSDUJ8kDfhj3TlUxDeqDml3zMy8yiwKkSTgvCQmQoWpbSCCLwTdzhRwdvQ/4Q64AtoeYKPMlCXimpMDmlsvP6UeaGv07kBRe0YT0YBgZIGvB0biVy0BMOc@EdYgHwR@cC3kzZ9iW@UMQ8N@YYjO1YWDWSwWEbad/V8Wh24TPZng46t0ElHnoUzdwCQ@NqUnQS94u3sPIdeJUekNBQvnC3DyVEm56jZ5JJyBKVWesYIYmReu9YzyuAdoMiihCYhtEyhAvyCWBf5vJc7y5gBomQW7KocP@pMGDb0URgZv@aKMUfs1pT1fKF@JBD9SVrgaBrhr7vmoxQRmHyfImOOBlqe6zGjv6qzfMNs69mx6X0qtOsuofbIfWjw3cBmRy/ksy@kO/ncJRvQxIz4jEfzAL18G5MdpgqZxv2gDgMVjGeCLQj9QA8X9PwQf0@la9cOKtDYQHA5E9ayOJfdUaKRkB8wAIl51rq1GrqxYbMErTjMEGsmRDUJ4gMTopYE8dKEuJ4E8eknDOL17HxeTd66qN24wdrMkflMKP5vunixqGDXlCp0WBjwmcXVacxIthiHhM47aA5qntmA3GzZzXNbFkX96b8DbhOXLFWkSrjh5zT7HMy/@ANrlW/oLjFKf8s9NDYoZE7kkxebMON94X1J4qpJ0pY0ju2n52CzLDWLyWW/E1LEBylE8@nPIjDJZPMtNe9Cj5964boSlq2GVg1xBP@xiMB5HQRNLq/WF3kbZQNezK6taiyqByECBrlugtTiIElVvjq3yoqJr5pYZdUEqVymyk9/LuuU51cCxA80BO21cjATQf8rstBINR8KJYH6DIk2Nbvhq28q@FG0DWaxJPDdEDsVOTy/3b/4erzdYclE@D9MJE4qYNKXmvbEgf/Hy@K4norjQ0ZRLKaOW5Yh8vlUiE9/HLaDhze@zM5bJL/444tLV9JL/35YOjzm19XBzVyDQhbfArV6UDSTijY0Np4/GACdktAa4xjVa85YcngWS4OxaAeqOltanEWzayp7lph9XWfHkM@ZwVJcEvrXI8ZojSMMEmsUfiYrX2a4VOa6Y3JtOe6Qye0ysy4NzGFsNI8jTXEMpmc9JnAsR4SMRdQyNyeZvXmGuOB6ovDjt8at40ELA7T6w0FJRgDxhuWtk@FzDw@qcRndXJSe@2nS0GdhrQkByXEOiq93UaECmiqdirDuN8vtCNjqdCYnkz6@oTlSrkLHSOUyuowjQXAwOfElTjxx7028PvTAQU4tZBFBzBtBK@kUBlb6UtXHqk6qdrHKcpn1xkvkho6SqG2dsTcKqDJnURZAl0/EoEIV3poBq1h4NFA/I0TsitaR/XnkDVzbgMcorl7BSCC/CHmHS9WJMuJjYuAooAbIk8lJBMOZnHHSjXE4p@SjxY9dKdRw5FykGzF2MUKIto7wfFGTPujItQwikRZE4yiWWmElx6NEiHaBPE@iECuFWgUrGmEWuSgiz9Bas7zVI7dFZNRKOAibhqZZAI4wRC/Hdb0CvYMM3S7H@tUPP/l7K3dWLqs0iqnjDVogM1BEkhArfj0Y7qrvBnqUT6StYgz3P4S4GXXX7XgnLYxQExiogbhSMMMEIuYzIDR0WjXsw34zPLINXzCqQiSscvnu5qY4eLi38z5aQ/ElAlFBrDgSwaqw8jzsVDKSLxWDEURSwiLMY1kxAqlGLELpXiGY7jG51@nZhgYWjNY3/pRGi@7yh6jpzusyhhCzLXbqg/eEqFtrotUToSgY5@Ebf8KYhyPWnk1GPBxZkjDh48gF4ldXkfZCvxgiub5ffu8vqDppUQI8H96rnJhVpzH9lNuQF7JEs8XqYWqvItXQIKQivnCIvvkTQuZzkG61EWaumLuiRpLc7R/8jSAc@PgAs2eUFBE8@QsRfYsR6dcDGrlUfMUL8X2b8XU9egUwEbVn0S4@hnOyNEajIdtILl8wfL/8nmwxwHsBvpmcU8dypLmZxMn4V3NmqaycjrT5NfCnzvD3TaTSzDUNIx9UiXg@@Xm4TM1usutkpu8rxuqMNS2xw5/8ZxL1kY45rB70AM5ozalKXCspbf6rv9b4p5kr0wsI5lc//O6Pwz5OU3s2Te3Pd8PVNF3sxTSt7VdiW9JX8Miw8tPUqfhZtJrIyp06xtc0BD9NG/dpdLCnaUseSF8v@ukFyz4NybcUEr3gpxcu@TRc31a4Ehd7vFspy32auswV9pSFHsO/nNJMWIz/Yi7G6Xkzn7rm08ni7wg5MnxoPLowLeWy5HAqxNquiSr9Rc@8@Hc93hpz98OrtpBxcYCjAnQoNUVoD6Gma@bKP4vHlJ8zXxOmVqWzBdUjo5aqrAVEk1bfT6jKcT63umo4dCDuJdSy/maVZObl8sBlo/vJqItSB73fnZDkMabnPwwekLwzfp3mErhtEFfY2obcEzSoyYf0guMvkA@iI59DStRAD9BdEDfo75rubrHKKSRvXIlj6Q@ZJbpC1@koCqUKIlKSyFcPE4UKllMTF8I/6R2Ipas2S1c4WLKP5Ec2zLlw8/7mj/WOpEdpGMUeQ5m/GOeP5DSQihG9lZPHDsnTpaN2It@0IBVNVUdA6tH9z@ZuEasunZc0wNIwf@fP9EHn@qjL2oX@oMkrefzH4Jg4MKknoLF/8kdCYOeWwy0jteY/VxPv8w6VVjmeZJeoJ6Wan/yRhaSdPEicXb9YyJIYU2Ussf1EPN3f2hM7Tw92nx7ghYzpGFHL4OmCHovdvC@TABu9JFiQZesg5tdYnDXymLy8gpev5aj7f/ld7D6jzTtWxTKG6dxy34@Uq6py54wRTcWlR0iOz0J5vrSA1nHdsreOc1uOEAjQ24MA16vvwgcJxhcT7PBZnm1M/mwybUrdsmLGc4mp/zy7ZVzGpF8m4FGHE@BUBc6fU/mSMr4YyqArqxm@3jlJr3mMH3qhXH4S6BdNQZGbzeQL39PT01IPw1NNxl7J9dE9kY@O4cqjI2AWBkO61ES32UB4XgdkW3ReOOm8CD8VO63By5aPCjLvTFEl2rnz9oz/ZtLuiEdHJxyK403viYWg297CrNApALJCu/Oi0Dvt1mUGGwZrhRNORO5nrL6c@OqTN@ppiGGA9@w6q91/0Rn2idu12n04yKywau6hgpypr/L7yGPDGHWJPJPeTwUxzTYrUgh8NKAc@AhclbIu9qaN2WGk@FQXj2iz@BwR81ykrBCM@azHQWEDppw/DStV1Tam0lm8NiHD1wdUClGQiGamYCIW4ZgzZaX4dXyhwjSEnEXS0PKn41BpNd78DebRUYQBNDGCAXftcuODZ41nhwPfPV0@zJePCujoCKHb0qyRxpR89vBnHP3@y/5o6EeSBq4fsIJLRSV1jiU1MK2w4oscq5jGDTRLK9x44aChdqBDmbhF3w1sT5qpkjbOMT1vWw0rHGNuWEM2BkfaU0oGMg0fngxTexPRoYEI03WXVCS@JF0o6/0x@tNSsEUYc3QAM5ihGSEGaoguFRnDVMyjrcLXMk6AYWcfuLGuqHyYikYsy@jmXM6/2fyrr938HqyL5NYTwfKmGFMam7qw4bpyubBHzHXHmFdoQXm51UeXf9bWgNzTKMXBXH25rExTuB7sggw6a0x@Rzqe4JfUgdRCwbpmKPuKmcPLkteFGlKtaRK@wlO@IgRZnjcQjiCSUMyVxaZmMZB0eeOgZ7GkYqdGI6fUyCkXYehpSiMPZTEM5Gm6bThEp20tOI8AX5U1ekksFH7rJcanYldEy2VdZ7jnEBUoC0OYUKSzzmFi7Q2j0camFUOAhLiAoOv2WpN@sJqJb3jVov6m9ygeSrVH8TdJBrxXAIHRFlxnpTJbE5l8scCrdI/cXsKnRsaqFiqFKv2r8H@roBLV/@piYiUKWY0mVgqxf7@RxEMc2WSxqFpZwQ058@slMZoFx8NBLbMk9Jkt6MxGf4T8gvrc5/dhf@CNRm5AYY7EkTvAx20M/OoN8cYCnX9hXB34/MIl/yKrCrngp9jmc7@JiJoSUWk0E9a1DQvG/WQ0HAfio77XVp8xRvnNFfXNn/noRsp3XeKBfGCC5DM36vsejGfbwc4A7yXK6DE5GPLndn/YLp@AKO@OyZWjD2seILxhaTwZlMndlDvo4rM4mSG0XkDTjqE66Fq3CWBN7JadQ8rzXXRPaT2b9noWOW9x@919Fxk3vD0SOpLKdpf4jpZ/bOG2tiSeABO2yu5WlA8T7aWLRtwVWfkYV@xzPGfSGMgakb5Q4x1jWZJmhoVK0fK9nlz/WSV6gIZSVo7YMjtHJ@IwCOGVKqcswIohkRLYRwzSx4wxnhVhjzBEqIuWJbIReSFkArUj/CorDROoInk@ewVgD7FXyorWtWFamWesrqJ7T7wrc6o5vVN4aCdVvb2KsTmoJzigOE3yabh6G3PIQaUvMOIc@6Yx@5F3ZEsAkCeEAiECjz1Gjwzt56REipd1cHgg/ZVUHl5PtNElWp9ivOD91cA9oigp4rTtcSiYrucTAJYsH33kjeQQFSKk2p4cAatNa4Eiq3i@P3Fv3Lq9Qg2iuEYKtDvsREBrZcCMrmXL1Ljj4KSve3EnOBZ996XbZ/9v3GyK/cKLkujMltsnXjffzBHpwFBGegqjYN8pcNrm1oNHdw@2NguiWL2B4GygqmFtY3A5O0/5ZMAhyQiL8PIttW@uMJHbfiG7Uc7mZNM3zGHPmw1WCGDPGqMcN7KzDhWTN3OMGESmLu5VBR1vUcd2Q11tXG7YlMkYoxZYanDVyl9aspCksa4lJMHI5ghlcuGhAd9g41kASt0rYATk7tZEIQxDCRHlWmtXi0W9plbpUxE21mJxne3Mrfsgh78Q2b3JILLbZmnttEQWNjn0lsdb29Us7Qslqy6OnexbfraO3LnmnF7ak9yZCvE36GErbB64g@G9mZo/e6K0VmBAco3qYS4nE7L/898g9s1Ds4C@HeTOkL/@yFEuYUu8qW@xB007y7fBUOyjUuBOg/u0uQZOUNcF2sPurEQhSbv34ezt2h@ZdYzs3BlpN3cc53ruDKocj9AOZQSboXsAGHN1TOtF0kKR49mzAbrFXUb56yuPHz2EKd9D/1J@0PjgcPlauZDNwhFPGkgORvoQmzuPd/EmYZwr0Y3Cg/HwRI7LuKUrKeHDPloOU@sLFnatjKsQds4jN5C99@/NDlpHT1onIDG3YAiiFzgtU@sHw9yjLr85Ro4VnVwrd3bkENTx2O3VmROa@85L@yhXD@DPsVnFDajCqdUIewCFHHQgEBt1bwCn9cODx4@c7FpLIFYnYVVk821NHEAoRDA2JpFAGyEdDKeLVBWw3SYRDPzks9Z6tC9r5dZ6tj6fp7bn0bDVZY9f2ZCAu/akIClu7CxOaX0cUsFs5DqYwEfbu1sHVgHKouyLiRTjaEabFjsjdlQdTG64U9ARONtHGMdZefttSsMiE99xapVKDtVD5oCNfEAAWl5Y4/p83HK6th7I1sgr0dW5O@W6iDmplWrl1sA/BXa0XL1ZuXO98s5wjO8GXdfvvO3DFuK0MKSsF8zeRkN@Uic7GvZ7b/e8Pj5YXV1Zvr3j3fu9r9zZv7lpd9q/Azyk9dwf4gP@eGQ2QM0kOysvX791507lerddvX2nV2nXWm4VvrvdXq9203VvXb9ZHLVeDEsnpBhoMWkjyt45KGu9G5WV1k33TmWldqtbvV27davdbbndlZu1XvVmr1M0mKoQZQb2P7Ut4tYe3yDfSue9Mgtbryyd@18';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://tio.run/static/379903db189f0b2ae1990edff26ee736-pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://tio.run/static/2f504a6e90427d18277bdaed462f16fc-frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and 1or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""""  
#p  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _yebeString xflos1''gem x=4721en ogola=1$0C0 codputs_e25y $"3"91/2 <5>6#"5"8=6028=+ codefn;or p#s4;931+R(17)7095cr=Bu8tt"?!"&&1/<>8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up sss
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
int i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef char known;typedef int macro;int x= !'(',y[1];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":  x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"197":"79");}int main(){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc27<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

To separate CPY and C++ this method is used:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char known;
int i;
int main(){ known i; int t; puts( sizeof(i)-1 ? "CPY" : "C++" ); }
```

In CPY `known` is a tag that prevents automatic declaration of a variable. Variable `i` is not used in `known i;`, so `known i;` is replaced with empty string in generated cpp file.
`int t;` is needed to work around a bug in CPY. If `known i;` was on separate line `int t;` would not be needed.

Image string broke CPY because it spanned several lines. Line continuations break Pyth, so now image string is on one line. Variable type changed to `int` for golfing.

Adjusting parens wasn't enough to fix Prelude this time, so I added another pair of parens to fix it (starts with `int x=!'('`, ends with `//)`).

The code contains 2 `w`, so piece of Grass and ORK were moved below C++ to fix Grass.

Answer (score 4):

## 200. [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 9660 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqRIUWQVdSupSiWpdClVlcSPlSSTZErJzKzMpESWSh96xotet8cP9nh2MPas3T3jXew8GNjBYh/W8AALrF@NgX/DN0@LwQL9D3rPORGZTF6kqvq62@sFTInMuJw4EXHixIkTJy7ZVJzeb34Txg87MvVRVzdd5qqOy9q2dqPaKbYxYs8Uzclnc6EQQtXs7qCvGq6zFgozmTHNaGlt8DPXvFYN7ZNqQ3iWMcs2u7bSZ25PcZnqtBRLdZg5cK2By8zO/GQ5xrb75pWWxJR9zegCmKvalq26FL/C2JmhK/1mW5mKyU9laNkQ77AtVf/c/@yyltnvK0bbAcgCY69M21ERvqU6jonJVxkbbqutKaRFAFVszdyvHTyfiiox9hyKqFi6OmRK03FtpeVqpoE0ybCTg7OTo6kUsszenO7sTIdm2cukabCdQet6OirHzmxH0ZVp/CusNnDNPXc6PM9qXdVQWDZVSmWnIwtsw1ZmkqwyW1XaHU1XU9AgLMl6qm6pNsMQ1jFttgdF0ouZYqZRG6dMtTBtcRw5jbbE9FzOnapPNgOEN@2eakAJM9ORsh85FZH1I9oaZaDYIxZ1eqYNfGSzgaO22a1pt4G5DH0US0B6NvzEmoqjFlYQQc5HcG2YtwYwkWtC0zZHrsoM00hSYgRcYfJ@Y5qxsnkMrR3uTYcXWHZ/OmwVGK113Zlty2yRHZvWaDq0xF5p@/PYOZfhHWHTbENrTMXJ7EiBIMpmkvC57GQvaEHrQmdmVw4UrK0yx9AsS3V5JPCKalM0pGa6ZlzzDn5km@1BCzuf21Mhb@ywyA9OqAWpqswSYiKFDhYmDuJgUIITs68Gy@swQ4UGciy1pXW0FmcsdeiqhgNFdlJMg0rcarrO2qoOCcbYWwnmmNi846CmrvRSrVQIGRNzYf1rnWmsZVmMR0EtoEg7mSJTkXrsE8TrPYcNrT5ztD5Euy2z01FV9km1epA81DZDDD4ta6pavm9JBRhD9UijWiAQkDQmUhro5FHo1laAtLYjaOBqfSCs5kYcpiqOhgIVkjiq0SaqWr6oNZkywfLsRoMOD1Uf2ITbUW3qcoQXuqetAkrFb@bora25LvUaVmNHqmKzU1tVY5NidyJLyMzEHFysSIoadX09sn24E4HG5SlSigWNaedOX78IKSxVYUuNMnwrklQObR9ssbulS3RzKQsMYNlRJcYqPzAnfXmpwncoN9Nd@z4EWENAFZ2lTctNK0kLCph0oYBpBZ3oSt5kU5YeyJitT7VFgOU4VBtaA4QPe5OgmrUGto0jyZioyjVUWjeNLtATKmsPDKSHwQoZaIKWCQNBgqk3QDWQvNRGIBeQwqc9DRrNwSYJdCw@HhJBYUQENhYU9fJ1TH1AcJDScZGXgSqQFDHuddgb1lE0HZNAPKLipbZVZ6C7mGZgtLHlYbxT2ynmFYM6rA18fAPZKYCUAoD1@4F@SYUCYGgIk6qKUT/@0z9vd7uAp9ZqgWwT7PqGtc0WjdwKFRaGQ4YMCwJVp2IBXAJz58khgxtF19okIBRjJLKgQlCut@ZAbzMTMrRvNeilPeUGejZ0rparcibng32C9ZVrLk00zrlQ8b7ShIalDChvqnaSPduEVmqpoTDxTLI/cDtFlrS2WcRJfx99uhZ9unipQuFiqdjyUjrdLQPDpZYpCHyRxzjnTW1CUjqu4phaO2SN3J5pZFmyxaRWxbRUIxqZwBFJROxmJJZCKReNlbVKK9XRjHY0sg68WIWMI7Fyq9K60Nbq5ankwSwBzS2iwe6qRlsxKQQihzrFTboP0jwFg8ObpHAF4kyngSTH6FQgGAkzHXbDA8Kk7CBfmsggIIdSjq6qVjSTkmMoJhBubr0xYl5Np3CICq9p9XgkHIkHq04YoKYTFcXOeqqZKLZ0q4eDFhDFcCwYCWzk3RaM1CgZHc0FjTPBmsTXNIqAZCGZeKtGbBWHdJ@PqEvyLofpkygoBYZxF5rsyWo70JFBCEBfdp0Zaaybt5AhlQmHGRAdBmaqdKFpIDGvSI1XhOdEIZNV4ooGYGuqrJhsatAJsLuBTBc8H6gbgOeyHAaw8U4SkD19ZQRYWnxYHXcYpnWgL/VBPIA21FJR5oDwUfmAgpkMqP85oGOjtp1JZvP5yT4208VcO11Lvgch/Sn9aE/Cygc7Ewoa1lFvma4Y3YHSVbkmxpRWS7VcIaigJo4Lomh6vKHApBg8U04vtPRsOm8aRDzVYpwHCnneemIoVFC6CEU/CeqMyhQxVQHN0QaxpI@mcweAm6nMpQ8IMlGAD9IDRfA0AGAydai2Bi5INWDg257W6gHPYukMLhf5IDSdPQQFcwfJnuz4WWNh5OqTbCiV9oOwGA@iSGKLzuKBwRVRVScCqPGDAY9jVpz@HMSmX0QYCAKhqbSSAt77As6@aZhzkAIhfbQIMhnD2wE0sRNUKGHg8tQu6qy@luk3EbQZTgTayH8917WcNRgnNLc3aKaAU9Kn9mjPPTSQWdKuPdJck7ubutkEsexA/0x7OaRbg6Y2nKoQhflteOWEbkAB6zisAiP3xwFwXTTScUBgUvgmAgeiJBLchIL/SgBIQCkgVLTjkCjeAaFyMjJaUSlFXSkFnU5KMAk7rgTTHQlT@XTZNPsohdg5KQao6cG0TzNwriBkPol8Ze5Q58t@0usikdSVqRnRu8ji4mJkLVIFyb64@BRc6@h6iq44uJ6SK0kuhEuhi1IkyIWxF5QCw@qR@wsP8zBWx2Yb4qj0SbOiysXaWq6eUC5k8cziMwaiDiQbQCfxAXgisUoFnbGYVL2Fiqaancnab6J0PmnZmiWI8EK5UbhfUCFHZND6Fk4jbbWMg@zjNOlXbBgFQWlt9aJ25PIic1m/vLtsxy/vIwlMHSsrlSZUCvKL9lNd2xzAcBm7WFlLyvVY7CIHg2SzEslElqPRYlKHjJRY7LtiLK5wakcjKkjt6OVlBIgq6HPR6tmEb5jIxmI@qaAcODCDThiNpO6KkH8zVo/FI5A2FknAFKMSiQBlWkgEhyqNnDlBoMPjl5wwm/F4iNjQtK/xOyP2ISwFEyyefAf4d/NkctrbvwbpylqOjqpI0ubaCHjTyzywTQ9f41pje6SxGjDcQg1gtG37MyOcjRsD0p9JuTWDGdF0ECEoDMcelKvaBAwi7mhDmCBAvx95ihCO36gLbcKE09TV1DmpJhKDjoPTXjU1Vxs64sNKquWMeQD0HnBautKCjj2J7lJil4AQ@Dydnh8TK88gnlaVaFbzpTrCwNJSDKRfWyOtfaA5PSQvaFY4lbA7QFVU2UE3UIlqe6wFY34XKK0ONZfr8MBHJ5hkV3GiMdQaa1zrQmUPNQYslGcDoOHcbMF8RwXNAWP55JFtGzeabRpI5NQ2oAaGL2MbTCGfR15go1ptL7v1MH3nIQeKzQTLAdoGsU4Tt@W0WNowdbNrsmUAQNZMpThj7xloKgGdz4XpJXO0T0SgWtc0RlM8qOJw76COKBdyvvatIGSa4FNXIGvY/EqPAR6o88ne@20YIeR8JgPl93wZ@viVDGCZriMGttgYQJhsdeQbbMn3qtUbTRiUkD/4LBL4yVR5x@TzegUGVCiV6OGfKGmwk/MQ6OdeVNtzzav7NmlIaMoIzjImag/KIPRTUR3ebaCG4algDPVIMYF0psHH7bsDsvO0N1BDaqtnMukSNIxslaXb6k0aBY4Egq4HqnISslJtUsb8ZMKEHHLNAWh1bVXX@pq7R@Yu3UDVZTwse7FotRsjONJUNyTmG2Pxiiapsaw1uhx@e4gDkhNS6ckODre2G0e1092KlB44dlrXmsDBbbXRB8VTVx2JTX/C7FgFZCL9p2v92DTdCm@ua5198RPGNF7y/a3G/t7Gce34HS8EoXG0/kBXsChrS1MAmPyEor1eFbADdmyz72vkjmiIpRySXp2w@eP0VMSuYOxAWPwD4QUM76MVP9UKdVstljS51w8UgKsIiJZ9GsO68ThCkqXfDxSQRUKJ1v6U3fQCSxjo2/knLOBjdPPiH04kMN/JmXtE7hgDxwrU7E6WKfzG7XRw1PaDsxR8nURW18fBOQrm6wSTFnpBlpmoucA@vhXCx9cX5uKbiZoL7OPLc3y4LjEf3VTMPFAfWYGQ4TrGXFxTEXMAfUyrhCm49jGOK1LcQwsfIq@50Q8m8nGXCDcujoxR0VKJCPIAs5w7@nzhwmmgjXTMI1l5Ihaj@HIHS7ZhcrKOIMgvn3EhBIJAi3OsdsodumMUuSCKJOgcfBnEj@eMIOsNpQG9clxaLyQQxZI6CDC5ME6c9xObU0lNbRzsg/N2zeoNEAGDQJf2QoJRfiLehN56S7BTZHkL2qY1CvTluywnfl8T4iTQu3Kc3CSHUDuyJyI5tS1vzWUijndLvs7SuOLGuoZYZsF24YLwFIbefRMUpn3NodXPoGQM@Yr9ZUjyZicTarg0jsmOrYQseTPfvCkFEZHMBrF6beKkeOxqZFJyHrH4KPrX@mzKDuiW9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvSbHfqZA7AmLGcwLOJSEFLlBVr/0bhngqav3hIY2QAIGVBLM5T0MT3QGjCvPJN2jYnCNNXOAJTgNEzS0P0FsGSpSJCdZlN7CBTogkX3nnMreTyAiUg2tZKSvVkP2hFh5sONEqd7hwQI/bc3YwxjE03hDmwXUonnf/xZG5pktsF6yoimAr6jAZQkbuk82H4iKXroZ35bE8zVQNcUIgy5voSypeD6g6L7jvmoUadhyWRPsfuocYvmBnbFH@hvj3AeL7mt6oO26j3nZ0IknjS58dSG1qcawROnjDRBfiD5lMGQp6dJl24qbcLCp0aaSolsbH3eLuqQTxICujdIp68op2fXY@OFNLc3cAf8F9fOvtSumoXf@VRZm2SyTF5pymradJSmpj7CB7ZyPWibSeu6S5XGohXmwI7r30QzVLKjK9fc2UDnfALwKtpat6va3vMhsNseaPs0TUnf0uMRVvF0LUbas/IYTlvnvw@BeLtXfMfDdNJ0@vkWhiQWaUGvQdLiAnkyQCZtirC60hzhdK337ZyFGZISC4Kn0orHMzkcdf3VkPFSvGU9nB6HakpfKs1PzZfmOUnmTWLSfEk@yU1VVGexSP@FXg9jmdZX9GS2HXA@KNY9M@jYNQeU5u7Jlq44wEyuaA71BpqPfh5jcByeWshWY9cj7D0ujrco9tD6iuiloie3TF1zsDvrD4nRaZP0OE/cHEE/46TomyVsm/Rip5f0XfMlgdlycXHjAUb7CsnG1xVw5SbAOSnzIaK1zFv8Pqht9Mwblf/OH@0@zS3VV8iopE4sobXmJG@3vsSnuDxOP/OpeD23VG5LnxsujPiTM4Ov5WRH000Hpuj4@xghQNl2HP47n4eDNNMUI0m25qB7fjJRKIulhG3tgZZU9K6pF4rdtAI/Dzb3wO6g3BfPr5V3vryS5S/LK08tMg1ZPB8U9Ndp@/pLnEAGaRsXrgLOR0bZeUJLLHg8XEGYTuBq9PzK7WSKlDKV5vaShxrAbvVulZH3/AljyUPU9cYSa0RqNmh9mKBUBIdrc9X7p@S28nhu7a8TSDNoV79UiUDjXusqDF30O9OkLJuRvzGFnMl8vXjq6AN1oM5V7w6bVyruR3xk8vH1hcqIaiwJy2IaiId2RR/qk5hEflWpcdRG36MCRtE16ORf1G3myjsLNHEL591H4DhCx2zCrjGwJhp3YvJmHD9OuZ7l9WyzPVFIjPlWiVT8sgY1oaw7Kn0fUuy3@yZMlc0@KA3GV7S/QEpGEP47gZhCxmrGhK1kbvb@6jZosqB4QItq104SzeRfJ3SyD83vCbhUgvmaoboj/H2I0vOEaNM09W9pGZClbY32HetJ3Gn6pRaaUXLERgc2tmQ4aBVpdh6yYfBxRkwtgXo4jXYfmTgHLVOPzAVnrOyPjFYBm/uXZpcwUpORyLFbnvshhiRbiJwqplYfZUeug5pNVVf4Y1hYeQxfKZV7FJ@vdQjlltZocF2Hr@SMl8LCU6LHGgGxtDbMTHpqXyXvIyq90r4aON7jQaChid850ak0rUs8kM7SoK8b@DuxahTQhlzTgLmUq9hdFScjOi5nitCH5Ku33DGXuHt9pavyYwmPiY6xTQJ3wPEp3Ng53zqxxjeltCAZX7N/nBWg41yrI8d7zkX4atSC9hz0v2xkm@rjLTSGfrFTp9JzV3m@oO4ZPbNn9NSeTZ3D9z3UPYAjXX6g5LFKQPl7inONW/5IHo3ncj0nSF3d1PWvoS7KQy4dTXO@nXYbt@u3Iek34R0pTYgQjy8a8GDIJiLR2P1Q3@mpAxiZHNM1LTVJvodAdTT18N/5pue9w4jDzjXVbvP9Cmj3U1ytqavsVoMiXDnBRfL5ZqSmbiq4q/QR5R0o4z2/xjDVMu0vWj26iulaFj0alj5w6IcMvMnOfMvlGtuhkn4NM2gu3yrCWVbtms1WT/tSkZqq4hraddqz4HDvo/NSIYyp5hpLbmFwSteAVvYohUxQCcaf4GPvofEvsKIzt/abA9sefVkwTG4A8A2tfMEAHQ/lL9Zq50TTkI97obw9P4@sWoil3Qe5iRRoVJaTaga0EvlB@8/Eti8hvWiN8QGlZ6reVJjAstq3GC7F3gAy4WmB/Q0QPs948ZAg3BXyDWaF0d1B14l9mXF7bdCp8GcuwloXT1jxhSVHN28DZmbo@oohHnNHZX8R8rEVkfyjSyKptFj6TKqDB21bumY5/JclO9m5WGbX8mehRvNnuqJ52mqHL1Kg60uaXd@0ce87qBDJlq06LbR3o/TlUpGLHMPsghRO6mwM7MHOrcLs9oF5usnkCJd8e6B2FdwLt6/htjjdmR30APP0ToKvQfx6oDja64HpqnNxTu8o@BqUr5Su1tqdaAUPoUddsXGKPyY6AQbNNsRtT3NoC7LnmN9xOJvR4vxs5LRJ3T8K97ghJKAXiZ2gLLnHvB2jvgON@hivzM1rUusU6/IPCjrNJYOpeM6t5/zdF49ZEW4HfWvgiMf83Pt4oCBoN@5fU7hzq4EUTH4Eoct6iu7Oty0HjKegT4mRcOx8SMt@r@lml70vZhioXyDgUOl@gLE2YFw@UlzoAcYcZqX8v3LVEm0TSa7UOB@BEdQcS2qG5j5uh3FdBeZB3hMrxFUtPDCT3sff1LNvxZA8nU@V/UclPgzpo5YOM5svQR29@wKEuvnloeULiy4wVJrGwE3iIcOZWL7945jOH/onVZyE2GAJYZotjsk5Ke8sapg2o9K5Fe8cAwvjaZoBDq6uaacYwUWjSjwei4V4Ilye6BoA5kHRaUA8KcQPGjoM6uASrNZhFxds6W64llmT71mFSWsSq9c5VvzQuZXtoUVH@Y558oslpV5ZiiSTkaXIpbHGMhEfXNWhm84FVyZgOxo9eHnHJGCGwrcco9urcZmfhHJ6dMoQVNI2qLZnBlmcUE3m53n4YbFT3BDxH/6qLQ5fwvzXAZ0QhkogCJ49Nvtqz7x9yvMVudcsS8HDm4gDpKrOjxIlN2sMujvowPzMpXnLznZOi@IklzjoDJ4jriP5peCNi1YY3Ift8sbjpfH31IqM/VRepYC5Bn0DZh1tt@ek2IlGW6wH9nivJLgQzHBtnHq1E2yPtVVcdqad82Rt0E3zmo7AYEn@w1/x82u0f17sa/ayp3OrgRxxm7xMh8ZaLXMApfaQfFJtU4BEkcggYwdox2PY7Sg8hrvK6WAdcGTSO1ZG2fCzZZu1E5bcZhE8w42nVcpaJ7pUO37@5iJTr/zA@mn1P/4sHbsThJO@S5YKjpRgHkj5HhkrGJ2H6HFshElLQ4ln6B8u0MThglveHkAihTMZni/weMw0LdFr6GgwnYT1uVFcURFFN7Wzd76sT6eKiWHVWzpfRpt6DRx78Liu4UAHA2@MUPNeV1mKDri5KXnisjxkiGf0FHDxc8i03R7PSmGSpSH7zHrIZMkWbgEHHyekjsfz@pUNb2dSLrh/LL2lNge0ReImm8rmKlSdpUZlvUouW22beEz24vvLYTaTvByubtfTjkfUy8vhd5nsW6C6CTPhpSdp7HnbB1t3S6lq5vNnRxkxSbqPlPl@NxATS3dHe0fbJ6e107MTaIV7T/zsmHZfGcsa5CLa1N0zdTqADHSxNdX5Bvnj@wA8GmVLClvHqzVisVBwvzKBClpLSWmJOwOiaSL1F5LPS@@ogfhZACHTOhrzOGoPBhJsQ2A2pBpWfmDhMWom0oqjoMRlGsp47EA@YXBX4RxZSqSSWAWIlQRifSWp2MOVfcrDvoZiX8TyONmezgVBivn5XfjxvIpzSXD/O6m3BQPlb19vjuXxehPMI/UGUD/US7NT29s/O96eTAY8Rk@SupVSXmzU58IZexq3VHlnX@lMk0iIprqKxCRKwL1iMKN7U5qqe6tCtYRwbPV5YuJQKr8UGjMmUKaCl8/Uy5wW0SiVAHWQMlZr6hxBRxsGiuiN0QF0d7yKvhDYkXzUXsFTksAcpotAUvjxqoFYBbm8rndEQlzI64gTVH8SXo/DquEYDbMASvXAUOWPOg6D/8Co5LmydTZkYjiT6yzJsvDVVZgB93zYWJmPUWyJE0Ja4mWX/PLiJRRQpvaVQjNm2sEmjkrAKK0rFp54F9AHMEtdYx8HJp3L8oSJr1/c4nxM4fetUNO2FKwNnfcyXDy97o1bhG9v56SC2hlXzUi@B3luYOBABUCB20@2hzDVAmbrkKzn9yhwkpviyL43VJIJ1RFHdH0twWE3mkMmVmyEDuo4OkhKrI2oOF49RCfyWE13QCdpw/DNL@oh5SRF@6755uukwaQw8GTKVxkTTAohrFOZPcINQ@ltC4bVDzzxEsERZieAM7K@mEwC5bqa4V2Vs4aWYDKRrTHXHuB@hWpkJolXhDVyJXtuXw8AzrnM4lJN//hP/5xfYHHpgvsXwj3MbIDvj4SvA@5/4sXIMvj@me/Lgu@Pue/7NDbZ7Kl9kb0w1T64SR348pk0UyeUCd59QVQXv7Wxpd/sHTGHzNXYln1lGGgmlDDIc5oB9NL6wBQ31MYIznMYN@EYT/TiDbAI8BXwB6o3qNFQfqpdj@LZ7bV0GguOc@oU7WxWh9xWTUe5Pw7wChNQwtKFfGFFTkMhkzceQjpP2cWttBxhLLYGMjF0o1mVD80WHplgktNSdLVSKHPeSC8p3@ekD35BlwA2xCcKFwzS4CkLPwXEVUWy6JISl2OYFAeyiBxBmdY2OauBNhglB4DEMNjwDqSBumkKUgEfG@rQJY1p5E2AmnhVFdrYVH6RjYcoCYg4brxoY7o7jjfH4umCQAdNBZtBOkewEwRbk@Yx68X37NK9NOriwhUGjPerOaxrgPsfz7mFhXMWnjCdvf4jOn15B9aGPTsxTNxEvQOlZdFsOptLy4VYgEMlgQrKi139M6CEzg3CoqVqV6bl1Da3914cHp3MXGNBkJFpsAiLVNfjl8lU4qLuOyJ@uSeJurGTPnm1seORMliq8U4DhBhvN5gu5rzcpkv6QO7nfFfybN4UMZORnPlaxLS2l9yh3Tiz2Mex6QDgJt8UOZNrNHZ3f1Ffr14a4ZnsP8@72iecWkbmAtelQxf7RKaLiUXc8/Zan@KVgU7KO4WTlcYXV/lnh7h/HPzwRRT@BYTj2yi8Xd0hOifqHxMNpR7Y7w11T6V5VnQVAy@YV16QNV5RZSzqOMNWaGa3SLA0TNRl9q5EcRDKJ9IhtyF5N905HNIh4cytTHQljE8zH@7Uw4hdf3w/hLgYoQel07Vm6Fac4fWOkfnnd1OOpWtuNBYyBMT0gbJZSOfRaxZ8MKVyMWT@ySgHdcZhimyNUbrF6LYe4rdUMO8yiTjdR3E0ALodmRYbW9G2VM91DDoV2xpAFi2ckL0Y9AGuQ49jFUcLFbSsJCQGeka8olzgDQyCEql@Ox8dxlI9ddjWujDiRGMJEE3fyfL4JgsFr2IAvao5rwZolrJ6CtQBmya3jhdBDGPrJfKOK8gtkux2frBRDwEyTNqMrXHLReTM8C4dwoZfY5GET5lmLBFJMT6TEvcJ0Yo3GaJSbLOH@wPJ9NHpaKSyBc@H88G8o9n9FNYKhhnOQs9xd3CQa77pUpEAZZQLJaUZbXUYxfPba3WkE4RHbs9vIjFphsXpZhNxj0V7@ooTTxYqrhBK4@tBpuRdqeTLuUnRUCqlek4Iz9jBpARyPHHtfXCCihDt9BWLRQd0R4zDUoy80cuokXBcO8aSVRyub5nB4nGyacCDImDOgqAdcml0GD@KV6pF0xVoJAx1jDY@PmkWu5BTqTq4KZMYW0J75iZoU2gJjIVgjgpJ1ggt6Bfwt4Yl4hdgpsRFmEuUbYiuaQCoudEkp7o9ki9AC6o1qz4Zn4kPCBhO1VJpTbTGpLQvMeCL9TkCEdDOkeLeHAHoK85EAdVQRgPUpq22NZCXz16qhqECgYBn@njfpzIAJrNjCe8q2sT4qjjKIcyLuCsOWUFBJ6@Q247c6Saoa0vpMpnGyveg1ny4RL2mIzSbUfq/TafS5bvokl4ZpUHXjFWjS72KHM8tx@NLxnJ0yUBt68kTtKjdL4Ey10jBBHUIQMklPVYGfgblr7JklJeU9ehSu5JdphTghSnyHST4wUmn7paU@/TSE1CWEhBic6ETXXLodpdMKiXfQ/mwhyylE8Azd3hNCV0wi9kvafE4liG11MAC/JC@PInTsHl5kibjXVnMBdLdvuhuU6qY3xIzF@NyAorgNX/AyuOAJbbMNTzg8QVyuXlxD6h/POOXuLGY0X4I1QlOvqTJmK8XLEJOo8wVQibKr9cBAg6jQET0JpRYDITJb34TlguMSU8LuagZf5rPlOORvAzTdJhfh5@BHp5elmzp7nIrecPUZOSio@RTH@tH10dHb2OXUVZikfDmoSSvSN@zUpZ93WeVZR/4sN/mEw4vp0Ph9LL8ZDWd/vDhA8w44HNRTVVBfPBP7CIZqV9EVxmrrq4uJwrF5cSzSCNQsFg0m42dsDS71DTNctpt@Jo9ug06Guafp08pL5j@wz/jYSJ/4fA8CCJCw98Kp@TD7HJVUZbjK9lnRhmKVsJPjsngxN8ifGWWz7Nt/Pzt//63f/a3f0J/f0bff6@wa/YJPtcdhv/k/tQOuBV0Nzuf8PYbmFpUSC5YkUg@Fzn5PsL@s30WmVx9uvqf/uTwY9gNV7PpcxuebvhjuFAMcyc4wJfzfDfhangdwQr34VG6UqmAc/U//a@QvvoC8GDMaB1@qnkPV2EUriYrlORzuFoAh5zNQr7/989@FgpXh@FPYVmWwyP6a4QzMn6KT@QnjIEjLa0WJdN85pV3GPh4YWlZzl6O2zPQ3Ni0fnAP8oF2ZWZ4EpTcPlcxwQ3k@BY4vO@4sPjswxZjKgy1@FlbezZD8P0p/3EqCZ@U6AZD9CSHXhXCxUqiwbP3eTUccExV2P9lou6@/xvhQmHv0s7khdKpT1D9MiwXVw6fDb/6w8aF9ogYHtPOz5xNh3lU9z3M6/TsW@BC4R8qlWMX/1418e/oBP/Y8Kd8APVT@CzCH/3Dx/fi7yKFiGACmf0s/hbdNRS@CF/U66979Gfj366Bf82P@Lf/Cf9eu/h32sK/49f4d/oe/9hMZULh9fX1cDx@DKqh4Nmv@ZzBN5VqCJ/Hu4jud/phK4eFw2chFk7W48n7@4vU98N4uSz@QWkq@z78cBcUq36fTK5/X43HL6h4F1VRzvVkvQpl5UWmn@/XAXF8/WJ9PdWoVqvJ@vfVi/XJRCLds2dx7KfPIGG1fnERCt9hW1TwZxl/Wg7@ZiUpTV4cLGB0LoGLkZMeIoDRff3oD4U/rH@Ixp/Gn2b0zE1GvpavX5mH4//DwyFEaMPMlWlnepme3AaJyDLqWWaUGQ0zffNQboNThb9MH5xapjPMdDNGxpDl0XAC1cP//UPTfXVoAjYTUrrDjIuIMx14dg8PXwG@DuR9BX9aJpMZQiGHmRv4z@goqOkqMHp@34hdhi6Y9EGF0T8lR1KZSKoQiWj1fMH6eHl3ny18lBKRxuVFpF4Op53LyzTXjlh2pUwXwd3fNxrbB1uNRhr5aH0p/iyefAafSjW@Lh5Pw9Xy08u1JLYf579UI5xef3pZzSXRXYhDI2UhbD0d/8bPGCU8q4uXIZjwnZ/j9/z25pa7yEGuy/NzPxZ/0hhELgqCD4Cm56afcDDQNH9P/@3D/7L@X52x6EU9xlj07n49Sp8Y/sVid/d39@K3GotGhSe6Dn8YAH5McndfRScB3YHrIhqrx@7veRj8RmPrHGEV81ivUuIxIHTYMM/1MlIGDa@yFBWLapeXw0wmVm5CiG9eVz7T@kysTDtXlpq4pgazAXk5RiD5lXJ5RbhXi@VyUbjlQqFcXvahMuARTgBSHaVVRkYvh60YloGzfzSDRhW6bTMSbasdvHb9qWXBzE4uZT5/9oMajbZmNxoYnvv8@RJ6UgQ3rlRKeQjJFD9/hk4YicGs78AUS6YlmMPJ6ewYfU9xFNe1ozCvT1xGcPOqcxmJYXw2k0FgTM/y6@uFlWq1sALuQjEWK0tLfNdLtBsvybH7pbTEqwHzsUhYRMnF1RiF3kcwnoXX2dMqcLiDH3Z3HyZqs5V8LNocqTE/QC6VeAhbKUSL8ZL4qyzG2Hq6uszE38VFLr6yvLr8rF4fj18oJsp3SkW@r9wpa2gkuC@3xF2XuI1RefIkVwK6FDPly1CjsVU7rTXwpQG4AA0ymGEgCZwQLi5aduSCLDr5Uv0Ca1K/jETWys94wxbzLBwpC7hkBEQXK5aowmGYNmod3L88JKz8uyYvZ3OL6fzwu8J2BtTsz8v4ubi4KGaL8WUQbculUr1ep9DPi5Tmoj/s1Ok2pUryQi7k60nUX66GneWwxeTVXHg5ZNFWotUMa@NqrI0WskUIhHZlTVw4d1Rd964XvTVtvX2rtVXAfrRf29w@TWTXAWV2p7aZyJ6cbYRl9ObHforOof94u7Z1eAYJjva3ayfbz/febJ8dQbgDoyQQCz79I0UdqA31djC4RX9Dpc@m5ihXV4plNSz4DDs//urnP/7qv/vxL/74x7/4@Y9/8We//uWf/Ry@fwXfP@bPP/63pTz@/vqX/@x//vFf/wUE/nv4/jv4/h@//uW/@Bn/kv9v4Pt/BsL@RnwDcPwLpARsf/TrX/7JX/76l//kX8L3X4nvv5z@/vin/xv//7/EHzr/4sc//Rv8EZ6f//GPf/gnP/7hH/z4h7/48Q//ISD/@7/@Ff7/yV///b/7Ff7/L//m7//6f/j7P/qfyPHn3PH//Kt/y3//7g9@/nd/@M//7g9@@cDvzx/9/eVXhP/y9xDy9eX8GjxfU69vDfnlTyrPb0ONcS7EYH/2j3/8F/8IOPdPue@/Bx/8@1G/8D1@TJzmdsn4OPAXjH1Og/aUefbZBwWU/yOGQjD7PImNQjNe6K9/@c//EoMnYP9REENGnoVdQmA/t18A7L/2CxaE/cWPv/rZj3/5D3/81Z//@Ks/QoGWXCklaomk/AUrEADmvwIOAQtfAweA8jouiC@yxVAWHIvraLUIyfEPH4Cki@ACLXw5lM@BLyRXyS2jGxLCpGaZT6vjaCyA7zC0UgIf2hHiMILEeVQcojbirFKpxEPDCsQRKHgxzZBVizhzwolDBfBiIp4m0SiCUsqGG4QFUlbix6yxXBnyhHEMqBIGhgXCoGNJzkrxYmULMqwMtxjiQuTx0Ad4fqhUi5VhFdH9QEUAHPENyBKgKli6YfUH8FcIJ8CHhls/QFGKlXi8WoSQClWVcks0KE85T5WjuscZ1RvDGUMz2tNnjH0nyUWJT@CAlExA4298DP2UzBhPIf4yviyqQ/@ek77LmB7aaUj04WE8/ikGU3oBAHiTSdw8Bd9kEkvzDKKHHFWcsoVHnGMAysWFvccPoFE2HopT@8bJA/lDGb7us14NeBAdVmdpaQlc61UpJx3CTIDZ12uOq9i4tkA6zhqTCiUJg3Evirp0RHOF5a1l@JXhf3uR9pNyciyHliI4lEeYl0cynjNXzDCV3qsa1WWZSh4nuFB4HM71U1ogAsVyhcVCUbovO0YTTtWy4PnK6W6YQ9AhE5KUkAslbmcV89F35tpa5Qd5ZTUET/IP8KpucWk0NAO@vimFvQsJWr1LrlNPAyeoG4VQtSoWuZgcqp5sn0KC00MmZzMpBorn3cpqdiW/ks/mCoX8alZeKZRWCvliDiRUIZPPZuXSykqpWFq9hwI9g36eWFtu5ter/2Dm89/8g3mf@aH4CVXfsmGKHR29Tt6HqsNkMp2lIlfk/Gp5VIGCUFCoSpoU17FHd0nQQrF5Qpe0n@oOt@5A0UJ3SWTVBfiw0EKILUAQfAAzmviZWHfeOyyLBTh8EQJfhJPkPDBDLHQJzMCxhayJTwhb7gmImycyd@YLY2cGnad4wucAMoB2MNg@7nR0TXZq8h11G2ortC7OplRDIVquuACq1kN4zfhFPbSe9mPnY9rs8ZeDbdom6Kg/HWZDMa551JaG1wm2XD9qV8Frg5y@5vYegDiz@niWRbV/bxi2@00oIForOcAG/Ni6ac4DWGVnRw/U8pV/YhDX/ejIIIAf7z3fPQ08T7drm7uhAts4PNiaeuQFUJ7tb@@c@t5VHuslzfso3m3v7097xQPnGYssv5pIgICEH3wm6EPP1NL3HoicenjkzCRY44TfjD/s6KYjRyJdtc@g48r4rrEua6jZPFsqySD0Cjj/s8LOSrmUk@PHUTm2minlW3ZlY1B0XenpogSzzPR6tdhSWBfkDm79goR0hEFzQrswLenjheR4et0N2Wobpii3Bp3OaOLLfwYWezAQHhiETlvr9kDe3ZoeQKipKAy@3/qB9Grw4z4e4PI8KGwmRp8DjotdWodlQikyYWVLxXyxlMsWE8VScSUPs7d8Qs4m5NXiaimTkDNyUS4U8yU5UVwp5VZAMkJsvrQaCoP00DrpNAh@WZLoqRktvDR0HW9fNVO9aijMLQAw2uJb7cKKHzAoMilXvMxAOimE21qZVlmU8L2RGXwrIyBUWIuFd3Y2Mzs7krSBHjTXbWYkqY2efDGTWd2QJJViNkF4ZyXJ5GkgCsBc7slkNjYlacAR4EFHSeqhZ7uAWqYkaejZrO3sYD5X6MliegC75jHco3ueVQAz0JPLkZoqSR99dABX4xmtUEm30YN5YswOj9mEOEl67pUnkwEMxxyOY9j16lqrSdIe99RqGPOCKp7nRX2Jnhp9JMkGD/CgJHXB0bVhPi1JTXAiJ0pSC1ytkQJhfXDhuUjDVSRpxAmEJJKkIUErrWsJVCoRjtns7u4qPbetdvlnZPNnC4oGMdpwsL3TfP682e027VFt@/kxxrx4satcjQZ2s9sUyZoN@JiQBmKu@6PpD5Rxr9FQ9LkxLyHGmIppjBoqlq2hfIQyiU8XM@k3XkDMC4iZtwbCscGnD6BN/Gz04bmhNCnG@1AMPYfNplRGHnVHloqGEuwytD2oHAzpKy3bLKMLdHC2GIlGEqMLuZ74VKYY1mcsGrvLlO8RpBOlV0KgfIzdjS6GlUwd9G65jBac6GL/qSSX8tLaovI0OkR3QVoDzXtFiq3hyzTMToRFkvLTQVEqrEpry/CUnko5cA6jmUiGMfiJXazWn0qriER6@jQpQUnACyAKJJRWS4iwtAoaQPkeqOGCmG0OXLXRiEZvVeU6FuM14i/gYefn57E7viFKoxq65U50mBhWeGmYFit/gsJPY2qrMNQNWq5pc3xdqP@np5k1qiRkX5Qg93Q6to7SCOUHPMeGaTQv@ybp0DkeZKBDjN6OF1JunbXQKaqB9HI6hoeDm/g@Fzp5CvMLfksBvX1FBaWwFApVhU50qg7d1K6Ku09ayeT5xGd9/Rzg8AQrHh48GPTZBrulXPAogbebulHZAJSZsoGn6VX0Lg3Dw1C1rbgKzI427gZrawL2vtytXCCCz/iznpTOq@dSnQXzza9moFRnRmt9/eJzHRRDoOcorFTkbLE8DNNZkdWVchTmIbGKo37k6uFnHQ16i41KhiuKS86gf5FZLMiJu2Qjea8rjrskr2bXLgZLF0m5vriY@dxdl95XpTpmjvoj/QWNjiDyyxDmNQcfJMId7QPEs7Ukfx2IXCzEUrilvWF2GnTlP/sQGAvGCa0yDPS6CtqOXMqWBUjIEnwTlVgU3@XD99ZEI5HVbCQSi5QBahGCif1id8QtEeDhyBPgXBiLgHVLWYi3VXcAChD0KK@Yfgm42lyQQ@H7UFtzLLZSCoXvQvd39@tVT794yUYjJZ70vE8Y68ZhBpWmlRRcg1kkVzJVfcZqlVr3uFYWoLVNmuekQ@ySn9hKphe/db0mvl79nj8vca0Osglx4tCSZno9Xk1Xq9XLkCRJYckztkeLeZgcoQXhhzDdzcc27zoDg87rr71CcilrXGO6qMd@OND0u2IuWSXVOwpd7T4cX0/jOmCqmiZitQ5plTwUNkzhRNOrC10Dumc@L@FMTGXWSen71e@L3786Ozw73GHPMmvFtSKnBG1beJZIyBE5ApR9BlqBdrwdClufzbz8g/GiHF6zIrmVSG5Cs7usiPPKUeSD6AWuTsC3fgGzrHoMXJVK9qlcyK7Jq7FwFU9NZlfDVXLIhdVwPcwTr0BsnW9Vy8rhaloEy6tyLOwkuQ/4OR92oPGLrz58htmxeMuoliVXOi1KtHS/fg//1fsLmEDe0zzynv7xJw0/9xwA/hHc9/DH@BOAC8KM4@s/JNf5/zr9bB7yQksFoHb4Q6UKjfp94/tGOBQuRarxdATfmC32VoiJGSpwywb9qc4y/n0/Dlh2HGfZ94F3fZnlqzJj6nI6nb6Mvc6CrlcqFYqFcOg3s5/0MkwilxdqLMKvuOGill4d7x3KiUy8rgzn/ssLya2Tw82XMMUGWasa@NpGtnl4kMIofLPg@FRVS1cVWx@JVwuOEApF9OnmEb58/GzriNKc03k6CqUpvshlaa@9Jt7skbhhciqHyz75dGYlLeeZXFzLrK5lC0wBcePg@XnhWsKkjKq1aVojrqFHN2OUeKGGMBi3r8GMyVHX2POjfUpBR@uXF7a2Xx2yw4P9dykvlIef7u6dsJPDndPz2vE21OPV9gmTaids70Ri53unu4dnp6x28I5B9HHt4HRv@wQRpEMoqlBj4ATz1WW27oycNKoTDunME8GO2bpW3clwxbaUNN7YOBls4OscVLzzfDJ8YMC0sx1Ux09qC3x0ZoheabftEB7k01psAXXxhWXVxt2uUi/jrLL84O2njJ1fZK2Vg8gqa2UOjNz6KtMz4o/pK/3cMVtcXLw0JF/OB6vhzwaCQbgFHMLGZdp7v70QLaywZZgDZFdi45iDw6OFjOdbOD8@XZD9uOOthazv2dtZyPmebfCt@L6d862FvO/bqL1cKIyTHWwurPq@re3NhaLvAyZdKI1xHmwtyJmQR6wbU2sv0Curojt7@9tsGYBi5YlYNLqgYyoYCBEdGA6/VYGmP8vLtz0zQcpkczQF3Va/BO2BT0AtoDZygXStJ9iyacFPX@0DMCQL@fqdYndbCYEVbzeB0SN0F1rACi1ghQB@Ac/zIhxbrLBsjEH0QoevQEf5bVcJJp05dGrvO4eto1ZQBWZI0HUpdHoTUqjiDXOhhXuBMtohw1SHtqQSKKjMTLKlWAyPfB2c7e/zzCzIwrSjEkEy8khzcJoWYIMqwi9WHUJ54/BmobZAWi0I5QHfghe6n2jN0HRrIimgngsLLUAwSd0bRU8wVLMSuLKJeNHDt5IDMESDOwMuftYtGm1hXbuq26ICxZCY24c7vIa4Nlphk60cY5gpUYqi@Sb1z5@Z57t0J732pNeIcNwCOS8Wx8dLWkHYGIYteIcMCYIOVFPKBeSYeBxSQ3UoLlCvBSA6fPn5a6@UVcgoE2FPnlA51sFXilAWmC5OObIkgiACQTAiHyLzi7ZIxY0tpJdx6wJ/hTQSEccRfoFic@TfHQGSdbqgU63q90K/ORcMmJ@UpwSyiOq0sa3Bncs2wI/iETg5wZrQTRLMi5QLGInziQRTE6wDwVMytaEZwLmqPZaJHitAZ6TWP9jiLcQvSqFwHkA1Brm3Rg0GwuIJdl9i9IWFpg2ztLIHBfKQoIBvkWmiSAgO93i64y1Ktsz7C7Ilpv6alHs7ax4f8dTADoLTiKw4X@G8IqpLgdUx0Ax@gQz7bwXQc5bkyOJxAeFzmQDbnoRLJjncvceXX6jE9nQtFr@5FiiWH6zF9ldW47erBQxrYxaBWoCIjwLeOEDTz2RrZuehgLGQUFBtfhoKGEDHvAR9fALBV6SHIXecPvnt6WGQXpvuytBvoQW5VOBJJr2tSW970ovdF0IUBlOC7Ar7zJrokgvgwjPOrAiONpeVkwk7k14yN1SY6qXp@BKY5wA8h6KSgyEDzgpjlCApBy97V/r4wpEKq@009g62TydjEV/KaYiC9/D125RHbBJMFAjjnSh6Yn6Joh0kAtc3o0c8jwTRs3Fyerxde5WA8sXY@rgHTOsA8CN6wkQN7r0cINRQWzAetxMselJjyzH2BEuWYMImgJ6vzkI3HRVQPZhje2BlKasMB/H9kz0pjD0yNCcrKcqiMfb58hKG1Mwqk/vW51w/Z6zm2myUW0Vll@PxdRAh5T0Bc8C7Jlc2EBLYU8FbOuZmdpXJsBU7x1y1Bxr3MGPP4qd63ePYRsOidxLTMmlS5pTpDe4oW8S9FTAuTqo2j2uRNDYiH2AodmMIw@GcbFpx0s@RPSnWU7B4Wdrqt5blSxrtZFmSvCzrlOlsGX4jzHowXQpNnbal6z9My7UUPJAqIg8ttJkcYZAdCnFbSuAWqKiJr3lwY2t0ewfKlEYDr/RrNKKOqnfwNdADuwVDPqrLjgDDD8ameCR1JHRMRgryoP40GdHW8AAp3rwIo84UQnobdYXunItSjqGQXzLHVS0qVaAYaA7D16EGM4QJ9oQfmhUPdgVKHFsTWvGOgv3BQ3YxcXEPxzFweok5wSCeZ0N9Np0T57PNnDi8n21eEu/A8Zy4q0F/XglAMDwQI44MzokxzMN5Cfi9N@OI@kWAgBdBAtfr0dj8pod@NdnigYuLiP6n9kAVt/DsHQZYEJRLwYGBtg5vqcC0LQ0vz55G5B9ahpTRYSxwftpnq9iYkxSnpWnT6D1MAhEdAKT7odlwrdUDrN/J2WIsEUAYwIgX6/UV/SGcLIAUSjgHSZi/@Zx5Vk7HR40sOI13nD6Fx/@NNkzvxglM6xF4jB3DYuN7wAt4c5Mf4zPznC43Rrc2yzgUjlZ4bH554o6rh6C9SsixIEF/2@yT35p9MpA/9smflHWFXUyWox4P@NcgYFxHr4P/pIy8Uk/mFvumGge5RlWvH2BfvIskkA2/g2AyWx@NkEA@T3lVIfQY8JVCAnEFEX2DfKHmEyek56Uejz/LFZaU/TRc4o17A5nVA4UP4e0JjQZeO9po0H1zjQZalhoNiedAAy8OeMFBV3Q2HpcCLbVhUmxUSipSQkomayebe3tJzZAS/D7iiuS4pq028NooKYFLixWJBFYDYXqqblUksd9LcRillh7OoxbIAyr45UwIiOdCb6sP3if65exawSqZX1Elcyqz8R2HX5HbMeWGx7kfy8nml4V5GW3SfVZ4QZitaiho@E3L4l3CePHDxH0DaNIXReD5OmTpc/CWB14kejQwTLQ1XpdAb2yuMLL2Sd79J9LMdSWit6OpBxGMOZVzn3RE72NhdBdWWxV6FpmHUtL4HkRRsJSoaYDfPQWNXx8xHtAm70QR5U14tkkHzZhTRR0LFtPCyl9IeGUKNMCRacGvf20KuP2LU8CNV6dgkCfqwI33pmCKjnCIK1TARZeowBPYWxrf2dhXhlp/gIab4MF8ocmNi4VDPtaERn2KnJR@nKIIkdLx8tuowBuLS2sSVN2hC1umL21B@Hn3tsTqoVkhS7cMYzEDqsM8pHNvgoklfgeNFFDEUDQ7ojSQNiExiSshlFZeq8PkM8A7nohB9XkqzORWT0QENUn46cfjVeDel8rE9AIpApMHXphxAm5lCr73jJT72JqvgoxbLAjFFbc55cbdmg8WPIjBU9RioUdmUv@/mScFm@S/0KnS//eTopmpz@95KvPIFOabZyu/w2nBf1Xo/6tC/xMU@t@ZNv@ASj6NcrbHT6nrX1TDv139Ipk3gmHD7t6g6S37U/Sw35EisPpNeoBX6gv5MV3gy@OzhyYbHNZ/4igd@k36tF043zFrtdppX7aPn9e6tV7t@B34NzL78fOrlY2t243nG@3a1lb3RXfzQH1drK3sWy/fFt8973z6qIL2vnv44v0n3Wr1Qm@Prdtz9eg2pxad2mDwcW935O5unPU3T/LvVm8z23q@s6F@3NKdrVenb1@ePs@fxG8/vjh68amf6TtHnYxS6ud2XxXebI7OjVD@Rjtr7@xrh/2T9vZZtr@/pb3biW9m9k9Kr@XM/vbt@9zmbTyfSe9ZLw@fH59dNbff68d7@@/amx9NpfDx@tbaS7dLnc2r4zehw9xreffj4WF3O1t6vpu@3epY7Ux2V7fzV2@PjzbO3u32Xirb/Z38Went1eio0Hv9@sY9iHdXzguDV85K3Ki9fp19aTy/udk@DjUV89TOqefma9m6vT0yS/1V9eXBbrf/2paN9GH@Tfykf3q7tb2hf1wd5s7enb@@XTl5N3j1@sX7w4x2ctLcVgpWs509uTpdCbX6ub34zdn2WVF53j5/3b/Z282/20q/6qkHtfaRfv28u/vePDna36vlnIEh72/e6O@e965eXW9t7unm0bVu1FbSef20/e7wMHT2QmtuqbtvnRe1q967dH7jeuVdvG09P7361Lt@sXFydljMDo9GGXPTOW7udoZbx4VsMd3SPx5/6piv5LPX8cLN1Yus9q72yQ3lPo3ypX39ndo3XsRb3ffDj3o6fibLm@/3Pr17d7J7YzdrxtnHNzvHV/artnHoHGaOX7x81dSvi@6V9d44OZFbmefq9at4RgkNz3YdaCP1VMmvnvb3X1vDLfPj8d57p/ApfnN@nVO3ro/f1D4eZ5q3hvXWsPe1/mamfajU3pju9mD4vFW6Obve1fc/HjrvQq@25Xx@x@w4G503K6W36efxzvXztxvyyTBzYBx3Vgr2wZvX55q23Xt79um4ld95YxX7rtF9/emsvx3f3h/2PqnFTFM/eXdthM7yJ8dH2VvjpdZ3d3aPXxXcw8z@m6P27kiuvVblW2N1c5TfGtqF3PnWW/vd9a5hpd9pHwdHGfUm3n5nuSuvtWan9UZr9V@GTl70zg6O3tzu5Qv2876hbRwVMwf7u5sH3fbKy9Heq8H2fvOq/XzvrfrWOi1cZ7c3zgtbb09y7un1S7fUuunnjorxU73vds/ioReD3mD16Nz@@Gb4fqXWb6q5Y/2dOVqV@5svrOzwTW378FP3@sgyD@Sd7Ch9tm9e65lPp7efdp1CbRQvDs/cvumeysO8/DqUu/1kuS@sF69PDjdeHL5/oaxo2rlydfKmncmdFdNaz87tFQrP5e2dTv9jv6TKn7Ze5ZRcvxd39q/T7c322Zvza/2q/7J/1QoVS05rY@/9QDG3m1k5826js51X9zf2T2X1rPvyZGXrIHP0tn109nF42t58Ozh7c6hltq9elPa7K2@P35Rerr4/dU6Vc/PtS/sgNCzmTEculPK3uZNS8bBnn@TOr0ru@5dXhQ39vCm/2Mv21R3NflscFa@tT73b7u2Jmml2n299VI472yBJz44ySn5wfTA8CeXenPZvVq2N@Lvr1su3hqwXz7XV9OnHq9J1r/fydqu1cl779FHJP79SSyc76aa@k38eP958fXTV3Tr/VFxpZzb23yhvh9s9913o9a62dVU6vz4cjuTXOyejfi1j6Pmbk/P8zam5cXK@e1LsvWranebuVQ9kQ390dnU7uNlVV3vD2@LL3tUbJbP/trhpOCtHmdALda/fPj59@bYW72TVkntz@O7AOi@eD/OviuZ5yTwsai9rnefD14ed7cyqpZ2fDs@2e@mNTa1fBJlypJ/Zm4evd9@fv7AyoaxR2Pi0aeZXP8Zvhu8K5@mj@P7gXes02z@37d23mr3z9ubo7cuT2l58rzl6fnStHL7bzp8cbG46L@I7WkEd7eZundpmTu@YIae/MTwY2lYp9/56vwsjgdkutZ@f5s4Np1br3O4VT7ZrtedOc@@FMhw@76zCGIGf7fM3ZiX0G34nW4hfx8YfCr@9IdR3uk1zCPKSnx4L0YGgEB0ICvEjQLQTmu8y/k16OXQa3ExPb@3kBp5BE5Q11jZReUixPf@OU3zFQYL1TUiuoatlWvREtGLTfxsnfDr8kr0Kz6fRO8fUoaWbGr49Bm@yxzmprfJDcKC@pEKHBuuPcL7pqn2@xV/DF8CIK0np8nv@nh26EjG00Gox781sKbpw039P2wdQICyjm6QbVrssmWx1dKXrgENvk@tD6MS/ARxz0DUFjR@YhbzfUORMXmxNRXWVCneK7605eM50k1@t7804FFAmRnRzBRqp6PYKFV/s6mg3qj6idyWo7VSI7/j8ql2QwTDcwj0ZRtdCTu0NBXVDtac2gFo8obfSml5@hheLPFtOiyVWVIYait3UXHw3aIO/YqHBc/T2vFmTew/p1KhYoOWKEWo2dKFqQpx8GaJvKhVSjLaS4/ECV2SPqiGqqN5uw@Vli1DSvivGPQHMy9bDuLV@93eFegJ3W1Mn8JpAqwHQihakZ9bsv3Nok6MPVA7xxfrtt3unDfFCDb7FcOJEzQM7LgNULns@q8xrECi/KPnstkzcYQDFR7Mjv48Yqnpjcl6WaN8jbo@E1sYZ9ni3Jb37GouO2CzajXKxUuc7CDO0dc8juJ/mCeeEJ4FSPRkTdEFsqPB54CvT8Q2aHGS2voi4Y6sqAdBuTu8EyNRmv98x7z3QMk1dMa7RVeZbZWG@YLcCjUWvCgjUA01Zfl3E/kmaI2C9Iam/DXZcUMn2m4UAxIZYr5nPDOzOtN8e0/AW9rNG@xjm4c@6dN1sRcfRy96WG163mJcTh5/K6hAtiR3cWWvaI54Rmmei5TKA4D4dkgmq4e1WDdS6MqYGoqNNPYFSAN@WvSA8oq6Oy5lgj5eWZ7VI7EA7gOYXlW8GQqgLv1h1ntXDshDoHQtWZiLpmDjeFiJwppeZa1pAhI7gOBjGiEf47tQZqvCdXj4XMU6ni0wd/tnToGeNb9zFDqWi2RNFSAy7Mc7QpwrnFxpBq37XwazGrEcNhTu4sQk14kWmwQwfw5kWj0@0UwD5hYZ0k1mcqB2dEwtiyK@RIL2gPcHQnjhoDb4Vl3X4Di5O69AUidYho8@f/Q4DXp8bj7wzgMAS/puIkcE5Z/K@LAha9vxeJ/TdFDMmii9V72f30tPxRZiAm7eWNlT1KAjMBr4oxGIQJLYsWRZ3EIS/fQmCsbGp7EJeLS5GIdUFwaWLdfaEReX19ehqMkpB3xVjMb8ziuTZQPJAYhDS1SqLZpejOS/xCiYGlLlJBCvzEWQ5gpXlqOwhyAoEch4wcBWDkHzHipxrJxEXA4h9vPVJGHzdyJzcl7Nxub6@XsQ9noHAqcTZ@UVfzsWzkJijXohPxnC0PCIQXp@sESDPZQPjSADFSjwHKHjW8cmIca5TEX6mwTxX6nMHp9@Z8uKd0/AGH0qObz1U7Ysi1hc5lW9Ktxi4LdcWgfjmKYvePzUO4yy9jGwOOgJ1Scitp@KhqQR//5gYtIB@5alRMXA4giBQDBARPDxagl09NtY1v32wQ@AOGfh4nRNMTrAiTENAooDEKEJiECFEA63baPUtHw6G4mKM7/jmAxhlcoArznh@ANoJ1X4vJxJjnHy4wg34xPufaAzh9I1Cgsb@3gY@3mwf447ZvYPn0IQLWI8EG/961VzkGP0qbioGfyeF5mpQBJBtfEIj6sqbajJ/DPTyF9g85AJ@GjtPSLVDCMYTC@2Q@EJzG5opsHFSenykukRHekWSD1CMlWGewW5VpuhIjhF/tWuRv0mJDr1RaiIVOPyEooBIIaTZ6XHt4GTn8PgVUe6oUds/2q0hZphgthS7zehdH9hBDEPV@aDq0zOEwy9IaF4npem9mIJeAU2w/KVxnHgA2KCYBoVOlwjry5l@Bp4Hz0tAEsWHBqWi0VatObhx76oPJirjzEHIW5GXWgyFokzzRkIa8GZHQk@OVlHSES1N1TEiLjA2vftEMbg8SXv4NmCWSS@Oo56LelSX@MXmb8rKZen1uchHzsDC1WG1LQXJr7RaqkOH7sfUB5Sq3qFMhGQJEApC5td@LD/42RR/7BU46O2BNOhmfL13rOZOKougPXLa/SQdN6AgcSyejnTnqZWkFomc@dt8J1RHbVJlfCgzntsVz@0KcuMCl11NK2Ra/eJqQhGbRx7NI88V1409zYyrJ/5Wcmq5DnR6p4c32ZAthEsdajBsJrrHwRxNyLonXpM98XrxuCfOV@4eV8oEYSc1MjHgjMdPMWFut4Fs0RnbBp1codnXwMb25x5DvUUPjZT8oJM3xSB44pQGqNMenCc@8QzVg5yBmEAa0mmZC5FdnQYVH19UIGRJrzyxgK5BpzCFVUAzQFqMD6eJupIqaTpiohgIRLEqRmG77XVyghwPZnZ7@kAXAmEoP3A4PpXAj/HxjIropDcPVgg1cshYZ6UIrqsmk5Agxu0apNOAuMU6UPE0d341irPVEJXzdDKNn4BBUSfcMhcFCPoZ5j0Q6mVenlvvQD28w3CYOBaoWKYsTlB4J3rPjlhOzuUCx38Pzw9YoTA@HYwXYrGVbGZ85BivxmKFUugn2cnG9gTOj9hxRIMiWyHP4NQddEFV16ET80dbw6Efy8anxUP@GJV95WqZz2AdIY7F0OCwPr7TvKniu7txvdZl8lBOhRZAKJ4G3grvDd4A2B0otmK4Kj9jiYJcrOxihpQQdVjVdvgb4@md6SDx8ZXeMCzYKjcAQ0jbbNEmScRB6aClB33ajZRAheFGtfEaAM0VB/0XSOYIduCiocqZwAv0hEPV4w1OQiESqEejkYWTkYZlpB43vQhXltSV0/0MlfJ0X6YhzXu/KhaAyCtYhWjM3aEFQeCZYYbm48viJVNel/SBx6J/nmlwdpDhk1NvHi7Q8DFmduav1ecYY4i7WsExaCg2MREqqlM95p2BIwngHYFqeXYIDkSPYZ2GJ8LFZ6NIQXzjusZt4YxkBGkRNErRkGIj1@EuHXFBGkUv@G@YJn6uQO@LiZ0BI3Fgzj8eKSCQ5WMcQpyNnIbA/skhhkEcUAreUZfT4/0HQ8Thn3dD8U0c4s3C0R0T8wJEwOe1pHbx8vMzafNrIfooZcqPpE2XlKJigb48H4xXWYBh7QJgUCiSR16lPLCzo/G5Nw@QSk8GqccKP5Hb1xZeZDcDNEGJryy6T4h7YaubhxQS980blS9SiW01Qs0MtA9XkqARBSMQz1K/F6YKQQNPKvDSNQMpuM7spfEkCcWIQ7@zIkdA@Y7lrHcc2BPovplzfK53XkU5J3tV9apJLUhvedY1i4bGybqKbhGsa1KerexqoLLeKeOJyopEXj1n73cwwNHRzVt@/wIOKJI4uSx9106w79q4GCJCgmOUR4158m/yrHOgQ35fGfdIv35@WenQrO/hfVWsHaJoD/I7pkO8Ga@T42t@aQiQEdw0yt7mep5qYUGoM6D0TKTLxoTZ2WdnD0WnA/KaturjFaj7WQ/TmGMIS4X9wPHQEPRJtSeAPbDPJOexADEfFl91HoQNcJGQzBOd1OMOjIjHxXhWmbAGjw9QP8iIQSxCdgaOKD@anmTKbClGGMeHyfk4vCRiuB/3/3KwIKMHC4LkoDUiMdb5a0b8SoT733ZldKy7WUJzA73LysLPR6GICf0tn/H0gKg11hf82QGfDwR1A6Foe8ogGrZAgYe5MT8anWCQ@4Pw4xtGPvIFPjyaBynpBpBgMrpqIiiQeAmzgWmRFZjEzBaTWocoavE2mSw3NSQZQnzsvBpPrAtEls4mcRmQO@PyTK0m0DE65EzWuDK//INUWby/muapwds/sOGXsfK4ZDmeZ1l4ONjb7UAotL6lq/zkjrzfqB3u@VdbMfFedNUxMchJmXY3fatda2kOGDoR11Yl1QH2c7ykisc0ts9gKMMLp9wUO1H5ZgXUe1Et@0DTSXUQ@4CJ8AYsA4A7HdB4jZaKr75wb3H/gEDgpIKFhWjFAT3cNNjINJvj0iviZA4vQILK7kDhu0CYQZNe4t5SXEcdqWlMmG7q8NNX8CLiNEzJ01jD9KGh7kPqE@gSaupKuVFCW4GC0cnpqVzpqrlQEm1HFOPia6Fp9wjaEFx6NXrThLbx96eKSQLdn2ga@ogZeAVAV8H3kzN6Uy1khZx3C9WkHbdiUYe2PKg0j1jJlAok7B0xwlE6HL9TKYjLx0L8laZreL7DMZFdbJX2plLyiT0tU3syeMec3ETB5/mTYS28nOvL@zT8LR7pdCCtaXzNvo95ezzo/i8g@0M7P9JpNI9aujJi0q1CV0CzzZXVTGEN51pa1yA2xN6Cl@gENHZ1aOGLQXFjAI7jXlpdvVF1lsNmfKM5AwA8cQdQpVDYspVuX/EAo7k1htkE7uii@fXEif5xlGnqkyEdPDfBxjNqPJnGmDzGRie4xKiCxBTBYlxQYyC14Ocpbnk2TYutgaOtNgddGgzwXJaXAk9HKYkmJlBi1Wgz9hSea/CEomORlqEfY@ev@PdX4X4iU2MX0M3rzFugkMohqgV0/QovfdlLjyMHggVWdGDA5qsaMCIss4aYjHIrAUDjGBblcA63e9LiuQfSNvcO0WpDGfLNxV4MVtESFzo@uKdkmQX2lIBIwPumkDHpCqx02rOMRGr4ilfPsxHhsWQ1inL32ETER71lnxze/oUO332yTneCMbqrk8gZK3u76uUyu/cAcQ8Iaji4syQZ8XYOoIZp49rMeEcKkF7yZmGPoQ0UIPcFSGo4ZDMclwLV4Bu869zaJVSQ6Wi57q1hQXglU/aowd8I7bf/eDHrCW/NBar4Ir1f@o4JdVpq8YUYWiURC0wTZcXBS/AIcQfHJYb4KOcHCpjkBmFNJKNpwjeo8oJymysIC9Q5kzSkJNiQddH6zqdPCTYSXrzkPMTvMc4kRhW57F98rBqD/h1ORhI8ycBKIPA9U0Hal0P4K2Z0Ns/c790wSpBYR0EeIkGBQRdeOJo27jIJJt@XKecWvQiKi3jQI2Z5f@5erEsD8a1dwFSE/ut8mFj7ri0leH64ZEAO2XNk64lxbpyIfqmHI/M6OkyMQHQwPI9UFbMOdAvjPHlHgSi6o0Ss0wgBg3bYhoLrjg2kXdS7gYw1hhWYIDVGFbTh8fu/UOHl3YIukEH4NQaAySQCwgyVecouxROZQfQN43GMh0ndZPzAWsNZtpd@Jh5bj/Dz9EH89@NL8ogOjWGiMYp5@1IgRWO0TCTwt6fcz1SXivdb1HemvFP1naGHX98H6OHXd5aeP6m@vsX4LVUEhhh64BwHp@xPYUaNb5T3Armd4inDwMx4hNp6N516YOELa6ZS08sHZlOblmU6eCvz/BLwPOcUguID4ZDnU57HGrhhgpzm5iO5mIGuhxfKOyHexW0T9cUoufGtfnz8An1S57ZtMUZTAGIukUXf9yan/JBBTAwlwSBPJPr1w6y4TOXqBKht17S/uMICWZX9glNF@RyMUWK/9jHGvQEcgarT9kUojZcECRVj85IMUO/AdNNJMGx@EkF1IR8nUyHV2dxUXiNiarG70tOESOxIe3yWNNa6pcBaU4OkM7BrQJ/w57G@vXcY9xicNwZZeiNxb5SGqdheh6xtm3wjNjsS1ik89gQqvNuzzUG3x/CiKNQBEZZvKe@YqN2jdglaPb7KcYB31ax52@Ki4@r79uM0O7MYTPLp/Dz23FdHbBMV/@YIbcncFhANDBNih9XCgqc7LYxN2gsk6X3gOjf0cYvDOHtqs0ABtpAfoAiv0BIH2R8TO83J2BvEkrKvgUiK66p9y0XNWuNVwOqPk1m4DDNOiBqAd8cXKSsLPuj8wnI2DpSWShcs7j6wyrzSZuYWko6hTheyqaKpL/NI4bgVcdp2A8XB3LE0W@rvof38XPnqNcz7v8CakKnHlQmCU2GSi5ujQdnBo3l9fEMp3qzBORVm4IDywLRxbjhKzMV8i/Y46l3KLcy9aKqMcPGUKE4P5rM3uNFobmpacesp0FR0dAARQQlIteJrZ7hehi8Hw9SvaDrqJ@YTYIdUObx3lhfDbOEqs5d4lhK22VLVtoMqq4K8QuWM4vEG0V29VcK2pnRxhggzdU/0esUhezTNFntai5/K2DzCotjqx4Fm88k2liYFbUn7foAVNntq65pg8b04Y@xJzUgC2Qw3aXaY83Gg2GhyMG0WjzghIeP5SHMsduJM61FCQJUngInzKrNKSAAY1U@8CnKKrTx7HZpqPJlHm3XwNRERR7wCQtiMkLZB2w9aTVIM5JVvkIHhWRcndDWH8ASm3wnWGegoi00rhXEoCScrG/ShYtlcrPBLDCeqGfBMAHHBOhkbwCi2odg@higN42Ik5pLmy@ClGWjM6gHgJIf251gB@vpEA1JO0G1ieYcOBY3tFxBN9vMo8pvjwXRwr4WtiikEpsnEEpTJLFoaimexGqaRDGLmYLOIAQ7BYl/bfpX/TO3HUAEyUPaAgMHj72hhbClorKSii9kn9HSqJTKyqArIgf5AdxVDNQeOPvp9M0Jogd75KHRnCBqR953wTqrjOA3js7M0vgyA7aUPabsb7k3AiToI7@z@GsZIp0LUYMP1TTHOMl0cg3ES3vthcJkoeopx@yIOB0dvT8BUDF6ZgJYe3Cbg0hmvBN82AKKTjosZborSeRvslJY7ICHaM3FzBe4pHaA9CPd42HhEjJoEBTbWBZGblmrzzIDbRuaAeeMz8Ov4qk8QkOO7NjXIVAx9hB9lM1YL@Z4PJIAHcQdQ4ZbDrhpIA@IXCg7gZDuCcnvDW1MVNgoc3PjqFr7REXOgbOGJuDV@Bm6c4U/Oja/Coc0Xs0TcU@kyeK0AdLaAlYzvs48uivl9zJvoT@1/IpXZs3V5sJyhxN5@XEmgXRWzZjlvAquVaaNFVKvgTo11PGEB/RJAL7T6YgXXWviuDbKdYSveAoOoit3qQZWgvTRkGNcmOrW1NpEN5nBo9vavMncYoK9grlyBNgb9Jl5J0yF6@cc0ad0DjeQAEh2jjlHO46OXGkk4LQ78fIlbPcl@3I75fYtnRfMSnPwAoG9HwhFUlInsl4Iw6B/vbPKp04kKL5pCskgW9F@IQLymRNxHPxOVrXs31/tTvmx5GqP8CMbY2Hg2dSQMDV5uYIvTrWlf85UjNLuR5HcVjezeuBbINyxjIs@ih4v8zjiOr2R4xrnxa02oP@PA0lPcLxt5PW5yQSjq/EAPPzg1JjBfwyuPNy37u5EznLdAhLW4BSotonBnFE/LVy65YPeZx1tz5TZEfjYoEzy6JWhdCXYF3tbClMnPtdl6R2hXE7whIAVHILRXcjS/C5Okl0eS0BAULzyf41Dh4xUPrCyOOyWDIfc4/efl9MgneEU1qhmvN3L@qFQ4d4zz8DcJtwJbdZe94w18P9kE@enlqxX/BQ4/jW4kMbg5tcyGYn8XnbQa8h1eC1Pzb8ZrfIEq6cLC6FuoQ7Twt4mPbfIScbPoBjTv8DcDZjlvTM3yPMHY4V1/zlEVscmTv@4AhneGL1MQxzfAGzSGO27MX64XHdRxU45LvBMY6ZNc@gB/z@t3iu6Y4iozGlh5Iuf/be/ZlttIrnsWvqI11C4GxJ0XiSI4XEoitctEEhmS2rUL4mJxGZAjgQCMGYjAUtiKc08llSrHGzt2fKkktpNKXpOUHVclD3lf/4O/wH/gnEt3T89ghqR21@tKaqkSCXSfPn073X1O97nQe@HrvcSoFcjVy3XXGnexKfjSD2VCA5V565SbXb3lkGouP/jzSBE46R2OEQev/5yhLagc6rPVCkCRyYp84ZcF6@pOHNFLNequvCPjHojFhqxW9kG5MMJO0IO34c6GpKq3R@4J/DnwsEUdP4v8kn75LmW2@TJxf2/3ydHOQeNg592dg8MdKkmK/NqgeDws002Zf47OvfsSb9aPOMTJvDfy4BzHE4fiLKEEftgeBIF4COKuC@L4iyaUbI7dTOqb@9Kj9Lynvjta5/JHzMyT8T1pGvsemgiNUVUJ@nfOAjg/D9t@jokfzkBySIVarz30ZMBxoTK4Z8Jmzjm4f@JKag0oBi1BSMsGPFIG3eAcOUApTUTfmOGk6XVgNbslqWOroPHKIfSXoB0iIAMA@ah1Oy1RpGtzrcLAu8BzIhuJbeWwtSB7P6iIfa52m6oV29wv5CGbvUH/JCO9JxgtIM4NDq0CxtFeV0NMRkFQBeotoKdAHGnuEXeojPJBuVqqlD8/lwbhI/ZvyVvBpzDJ/5R23vN2@onxk5LM9lUMAIPHmcVs6CJhkxIt6JKjNUUN6mIVLcmKPp05ebo1uUS//Fu2IE8xIJetW/lijMY/X3vua5tZf2YfC1@8GU4iAUeschT5JqqYzj4/g53/K1Yjr2cucpUVxZemE8mmEzKg2usYT2QXs6R9jJzH7h5f2ONVk77@8ZV2twxnFOPJ1K4VUbTVEWyiSvNhPBqpiXw9JfqIBn1Erfw3pg6f3tcEW4Cwu8lqx6/Ra8M4ItLRymtpwutAPVeouJva@rNI@1W9pto@qrSPpsh7hhdpuOZkc6Mq0rTbvHolImrgbOnCOr5E/lLDXJu3KKfyxmWcUkaXZ4e6M@OSMfV3vhRMKK2DvAUyRhaH14qGmJPUatokSrhKLaIQL@WonMI1mx@/mNp6OILhZSk5ETMv8WVb7UUcGwxERWcD2h7k4nMUQRlexqahjE6Nmou0yuRCm7MJ0S/w/1@srTQJsoHHl0ZWv0Ujqy@tRr60GvnSauQyq5GFm@WxPyq3vH4ZWLOeKJ4D959ZgAW1vSfee@fekTh6Z0c8fPrgd8VX956K9@49gZQ9sf/0/qPdBwL@7zw53BFUQP@8645Q5V7A1G@7bZdu55cqlRVBmOcClK@Iw@aZeGfQdl8C8Wz4zbOtU/5S6rvBJpfaeemOpgN@DhqiMksgrSborojfmtSNE1pct4CSz/AdUfnyxDaSN0@fb5bI9oLCoWsDbn7bIx6E9LjoWUkbbQD8AFIBTZOfZEl3Gp/WiWnplIQcOP3z2iMITOHjQ3HvyTZG@tzePdrde3IoHu4dwNf9r6KbHbG9i25j7j/FLAJ8vLe9@3D3wT1K4AZUSgLv1shg/bImlBCcRqX9ojvG8GA9lArlt4hX74VMpj9QVhG@yI77ofueDpAUvruzs9MauWi3b907ePtd5GrcrwnLwiCXhkN1aYFwq4JGI1CbjKJdY2fqyFoWq7whnU3FLcyuZegOiD4XhEKeo3dizxXWA7xGxAdpipvNDJtCDRXdBNyISjmCdQRFYMhmCxuEchNqo9sDVRterHbVFyy6JR2zohy5oLy0@oQUgzPu9tscRlclAN2zVjdVG4wYAC@EZAID4B0MJgTNF@4uXpKIVQkxDlDwh4TbnPD8bPjwHLlGNHCVCfc5EMiabBPPG00pBjhqen2ex4hZE@8OFCOFivgEj05yej115UoqccD/yzc2fJUFSAt2wS6sbCVUhM9uQA2wt582u4EvbCeHt8Eggrh9jzW1TnpNEPfoXniEBksvUY2Aql1z8GdTOapXDCcF4lQiTGsqou3Q5bblwe9etxyUvD9XI@rtUadRYUrGf7qyAffnGvBp0ACiorlfoFuhYUCMLaEZdCUp2/4AKBJEPvFRNKrRoDNuu5ECUtaxn3sffpiTg1wIixgqPtQ6rWGHoR7wIeQcfVCRmwsQYkhT8hRfo3gO7WgPwrfhM1SGGGEDP1CDK2szhQdVo9TEkZUiP59Sa6tJxnBX1koUz7rBevsaap9R9Pzts1kePZO0UEzW0pyP/pxRiQE9O43QzUtXoGLRNKCWcHCHTLh3fCT8cv39NWdz@/6z4kcfFI7L5RPeFpodfrxgpUR@ZiGRHJaH1p0kbUC10iTSjD9uYWmlz8i7Ja5yhQwYl1MPmO@tRk3n8bXqfHqf4mVF0ynx1SuHSxXJ3oRICCPJhLtbQdRVlQUqcyxyEkG4d0Jj0bOuSikQTr1fb2Fce5yFGoxIH/cRUq8xw6qRfo3h7Rof9GBnyUg@jadb48@pWOSSoujHNuej/L5938lv5soKihaTHk5bbdEFhbmak72a4fTSeTWHbvtydLB/Xx/d2qWt4@PhtbBtX4rttdpWzKfj4mPJwHV9tB9dgpYPt0@FFvpeSEfMh@Q8Nk3pmjgLtxYUzV9R4wdzc0drD9Dg2YsRVTVSo7Zxv4ce4my@FIemUYGciSZkiA6PtncODoS1g7ds61AW9r1mv032pbgNIu6bytMR2yHTZlfSTJMOE6SZJ5UyY/PSaLWXLebEwUvZKiQPUpDjoTcLHbUXJJOJtI7gk4VYCDS85g1RjVy0dRdqD/LrEvGsjppQIpw0o4OZxG4u8OHDTvZpkwnHrcC8sf/CG2pmxp1IZ110VT2amogUI4zHQfMEX76T5@895o/XVT3MYLlfG1OHUQm/jf7yxSFUPMSX4lJ0Bi@ZFjWlpLNCVLqgxo7M8qIc9mcnKB2LfSZ5YWNbl8yxbBrzx7eMSHbEn27hO/9UZrbP5H2n2uIpZcOc0Fx46NnRIwiYTBCDxZZJFVD8eCaPMBoNfU46miE319otak1dtZKimUnctXSgN4CDX70d3x7iVcFue2lVxc@nKj4lIjUZcbfma1CZgPn26uryVbjjvVDFi58VN58h8f0zOBu@bBoo/alPqkJAubtPCio/JIBLhs4BKbBjqwUTKwisTsKZEuk7HUZm@6At5yO0xYPG7D09KuB9UbzWnJjE2paMnU8kEzuBzPXBWMK6o7xq5kZ/dnl19ymo2xX13Xz9@nixIRDeh89@zWEyDwZD3CqBER812CsqiOTrPmrFBViCgw9qT79GDMwtFceyzvHmtviFG22kucatYPAC9fpV5EwZ28zCZ6jSWXN48QovuF7RlSnnoU2ALOsVxNZz1lHhyJpbnQEpEXR1KMstbmU0Dbb5lw0z@OY6qg9SHgMYD5iOHsDsm1kBcs863iqoUJPZPKcBf6KTipwEtBqg7KHTFzkd7RK8YW@q08uc3nEx8JxO3ZBYzps64mV2U0LGI2RmLQlMd7Ved9qgYdfZb3E2sDE66Q3ZGJAtewOdepNTUadKJdVl2XGYdMxJIEnppAUJhQeTF5i05LvuiwZNsow2BwizBdH3esclqT/1li1lx5w04Qh4IqG82@9kaFIo5qlGpY6ELXQtK0movuUdl0iBUm5AKJOFE8sLacsLC5jAkG6EvmSi4mLUAPwtGyGbahIv1lzfeo4UPnL99tgVOxOU8VVsREWV5BhkQew82RZ7D8XB3v5OFDW2uIE8CpVSCnsUilk2jLqjlmwBJnwwDk4bnKi@xnPPXc5VKPi7BuoPRgYQf43nqgoIxTEuS3HxqvNK1OHwHupJsTu5Yznpqse6D6X2YNwPLl5NXtH0ToDTKwEJvCVmJbwkeGtuWORKlBy2Igd6i8OwkMhXNpRbhbAWSqFaJtI3x0BaXMfWfG4msWX0/glTByuTNukwICdsk7gTDJDlWZfxLWE42qdhwE16y3aEbccbhodSqTSXnBd3dOBG14y4G63smpXk0yq5G1bCFKbxlHyMIxrWlhOdgXjlvVKVhYcKHv1rcWlHjzb6bpbTaBwxtOwiMJVjI5tfJYw@dzLRT3MLTs6giMYbla8bvCAwyHu4mztM4xEwou85ML05KDBeQHNwtAoigLxM5gCp/DzGRnIrw6WXUCS5xeF6nG9OSi0huoQiybWEjY5ORbjWY7PRHgB3xgFJ8EMDBEHjfE2cOSCbuYrTFquIF5SkSOJMg@u0@U8uoQ61TTME0OOx@lg9ZtMbkTWLXQofHRGzBbLzxoDgHkTuVPBYM9Or8XTzSBKbRvE4hNGoGDDgjJ1UV88FexKJJJ2jpRYvKzLaktHAkdeSRyNsOccGKJFQCmgxCsqrJoQFUAQhLg5PFgOUV2IUNJ8MahA/wZtYY201VqMGzSeDGutjDmsxCWsUNB8HndvXaKOMjr1maBftyycvl8LHmuiMqtyJ2x4HfNIopxWwhgJYHiajJaE73okXvCVCRos@laA9SLQra9IjtkoDAX/1jmZ9qIBitc0myGpDhLhbGLyUl1AxX0eZ7FvImGvmMQLPIa7xfdwArROEOQ2CPTDJhigmQwo06hRTrJg5NFxqEogaGSMJSyxcwNcZcr/1hQsWdzjyu1WwcjOLm1WL7KLQJ5Us5aONDTUWpWDQ8ETiT002nnAMhiKKoxQmXfITwTEOdCpecRR6gzZfdhYQV00Ja3VIRwGcHnZiOPA1Zb4vqiCgOb66HfigMo8Dm5AXl3XKxKGEqnkci9fGoQS2eRzF67eD5KmkvrxxbRwsCCbhKF8bB1Lg/JhaCxeAYMa/rSRSi4wHmkXJ1GahFSUNjbMZ@daK90WJqgLtBQlDBH4S@5bUDsmYm7TeM8Sga40HCh3z42F7vJI24SimnbvCF8xVLJmbWy8s3FIq38AaK68mbvlBBw6CUren13fC4o@J6LFLEomQ7j1QiCm1T0cgIuFslqT0oRgQwgntbzRQNavRoJuh/YO9tw/uPW48ufcYhagF3qPw@ga1ZUhdp1Jawnj2fNvSIJ0iR6CqBXYjQ/uwkUftk2h26BShyLFYauHCgJtZzEBhTQ7dF5X67rl4CFkUtH4OJ0KW9N0MTI9NbdCbulV8aeVCSPMEU72S8tomtIRgmE5kSwjGSM4YwhaXf9ZnDZVn/WcBA7ZEnW0y/WOzvc/QcMkoKETx5bPgXXfUQl2SonZayrOIKvgou5FzKlS5kDfoIQZjAn9dLov7yimutF9r9tro8nbcJce3Z16vedbqNEvD02Gm6zvSPY2d7fro5DKDylS7RzsHh419jNO184AsJ/CnRnlHu4939p4eYc4hZC3L5J2Dg72DBimoHzzdP0KPobEkywSUWEIwmRABerL3zr1HBgx/t2Qj2SDEB3kT/khXPgXhDRsT@j0lM48Cq0I0KAgPmalgUUoriMA7cwdjFbwN/U@oA76Alif4KAN1qajG5JDGxutPmRf6Op0ZUNSO0XgYEChpwNuxkchFSzDMmX@CBcgXkQ98O2nTl/hGGfPQkG8wtGNl0UAGi2WkfVfXp9WBy@Rw2m/bCp105Fm4cPsAia9N2XHQLa5lZzn0KjkkpaF44WwZTo4yOUfNJpeUIyi10jNGECPz2rWWUQbvAEUWJTQJoWUKFeAXxJrI573cRcYMECWzYFfl@FEXwrChj8LI@DU3jDlit6as5wv1I4HoT9ICR9MIf903H6WIwOT7FBlz1NHyXI8Z/VWd5RtmW8@OTe9ToV13CbVHHkCD7wU2O3ohn30h3cnnLtmABmbEZzyaB@jl25jsMFXINO4HNRioYDQVbEHoB3q4oOfH@HsiXbu2UYHGBoLLmbCWxbnsjhKNhPyAAUjMszat9dCNDZslaMVhhtgwIapJEO@bEEtJEC9NiOUkiE8@ZhCva@fzavI2xdLqKmszR@Yzofi/6eLFooLdUKrQYWHAZxZXpzEj2WEcEjrvoDmoeWYDcrNlty9tWRT1J/8OuE1cslSRKuGGX9LsSzD/4g@sdb6hu8Yo/S330NigkDmRT15swoz3hQ8kiasmSVvSOLafXoLNstQsJpf9TkgR76cQzSc/i8Akk8231LwLPX7qhetGWLYaWjXEEfzHPALndRA0uLxaX@RtlA14MXtpXWNRPQgRMMiyCbIUB0mq8tWlVVZMfNXEKqsmSOU6VX7yc1mnPL8SIH6gIWivlYOZCPpfkYVGqvlQKAnUZ0i0qdkPX31TwU@ibTCLJYHvh9ipyPHl7f7F1@PtDksmwv9hInFSAZO@1LQnDvw/XhfHciqODxhFsZg6blmGyOdTIT75cdgOHt74Mrtskfzij68uXUkv/fth6fCY31QHN3MNCll8C9TqQdFMKlrX2Hj@YAB0SkJrjGNUrzljyeFZLA3Goh2o6mxpcRbNXlLZ08TsZZ0dQz5jBktxSehfjxijDY4wSKxR@JmsfJnhUpmbjsm15bhDJrfLzLo0MIex0TyONMUxmJ7NmMCxGBEy5lHL3Jxk9mYZ4oJricKP3xw1T/tNDNDqD/olGQHEG5R3zgbPPTyoRmV0c1F67qdJQ5@FtSYEJMc5KL7eQ4UKaKp0KsK63yy3I2Cz3R6fjXv4huZIuQodI5XL6DKOBMH@@MyXOPHEvT/2etADBzm1kEUEMW8IraRTGFjpa1Ufqzqp2vkqy2XWGy@RGzpKora1R94woMqceVkAXT4RgwpVeBsGrGLh0UD9ghCxK1pH9ueR13dtAx6juHoFI4H8IuQdLlUjyoiPiYGjgBogT8ZnEQwXcsZJN8bhnJKPFj92pbCEI@ci3YiRixFCtHWE54sl6YOOXMsgEmlBNIpiWSqs5HiUCNE@kOdZFGKlsFTBioaYRS6KyDO01ixvdsltERm1Eg7CpqFpFoAjDNHLcd2sQO8gQ7fLsX71w4//3spdlMsqjWLqeP0myAwUkSTEil@PBvvqu4Ee5RNpqxjD/Q8hbkbdcdveWRMj1AQGaiCuFMwwgYj5AggNnVYNerDfDE5swxeMqhAJq1y@t70tjt452HsPraH4EoGoIFYciWBdWHkedioZyZeKwQgiKWEe5rGsGIFUI@ahdK8QTPeY3Ot0bUMDC0brG39Ko0V3@QPUdOd1GUOI2RY79cF7QtStNdHqiVAUjPPwjT9hzIMha88mIx4MLUmY8HHoAvGrq0h7rl8MkVzfL7/3F1SdtCgBng/vVc7MqtOYfsqtywtZotli9Ti1V5FqaBBSEV85RN/8CSHzOUi32ggzN8xdUSNJ7vYP/kYQDnx8gNkzSooInvyViL7FiPTrAY1cKr7ilfi@zfg6Hr0CmIha02gXH8M5WRqh0ZBtJJevGL5ffk@2GOC9AN9MLqljMdLcTOJk/Ks5s1RWTkfa/Br4U2f4@yZSaeaahpEPqkQ8H/88XKZmN9l1MtP3DWN1xpqW2OGP/zOJ@kjHHFYPegBntOZUJa6VlDb/1V9r/JPMjckVBPOrH373x2EfJ6k9m6T257vhaprM92KS1vYbsS3pK3hkWPlJ6lT8LFpNZOVOHONrGoKfpo37JDrYk7QlD6SvF/3kimWfhuRbCole8JMrl3warm8rXImLPd6tlOU@SV3mCnvKQo/hX0xpJizGfzEX4@SymU9d8@lk8XeEHBk@NB6dm5ZyWXI4FWJtN0SV/qJnXvy7GW@NufvhVVvIuDjAUQE6lJoitIdQkw1z5V/EY8rPmK8JU6vS2YLqkVFLVdYCokmz5ydU5TifW11LOHQg7iXUsvnpKsnMyuW@y0b342EHpQ56vzsjyWNEz38YPCB5Z/w6zSVw2yCusLUNuSeoU5OP6QXHnyMfREc@h5SogR6gOyBu0N8N3d1ilVNI3rgRx9IbMEt0g67TURRKFUSkJJGvHicKFSynJi6Ef9I7EEtXLZaucLBkH8mPbJhz5eb9zR/rHUmP0iCKPYYyfzXOH8lpIBUjeisnjx2Sp0tH7US@aUEqmqqOgNSj@5/N3SJWXTovaYClYf7On@mDzvVRl7UD/UGTV/L4j8ExcWBST0Bj/@SPhMDOLYZbRmrNf64m3ucdKq1yPMmuUU9KNT/5IwtJO3mQOLt2tZAlMabKWGL3iXh6uHMg9p4e7T89wgsZ0zGilsHTBT0Wu3lfJgE2ekkwJ8vWQMxfYnHWyGPy8gpefilH3f/L72L3GW3esSqWMUyXlvt@pFxVlbtkjGgqrj1CcnzmyvOlBbSO65a9dZw1OUIgQO/2A1yvvgsfJBhfTLDDZ3m2MfmzybQpdcuKGc81pv7z7JZxGZN@mYBHHU6AUxU4f07lS8r4YiiDrqym@HrnJL3mMX7ohXL5SaBfNAVFbjaTL3zPz89LXQxPNR55JddH90Q@OoYrD0@AWegP6FIT3WYD4XltkG3ReeG4/SL8VGw3@y@bPirIvDVBlWjn7ptT/ptJuyMenpxxKI5Pe08sBN32FqaFdgGQFVrtF4XueacmM9gwWCuccCJyPyP15cxXn7xhV0MMArxn11mt3ov2oEfcrtXqwUFmhVVzDxXkVH2V34ceG8aoS@Sp9H4qiGm2WZFC4KMB5cBH4KqUdbE3qU@PI8UnunhEm8XniJiXImWFYMxnPQ4KGzDh/ElYqaq2PpHO4rUJGb4@oFKIgkQ0UwUTsQjHnAkrxW/iCxWmIeQ0koaWP22HSqvx5m8wj44iDKCJIQy4a5fr7z@rPzvu@@754nG@fFJAR0cI3ZJmjTSm5LOHP@Po9172hgM/ktR3/YAVXCoqqX0qqYFphRVf5FjFNG6gWVrhxgsHDbUDHcrELfpeYHvSTJW0cU7peduqW@EYc8PqsjE40p5SMpBp@PBkmNqbiI4NRJiuu6Qi8SXpQlnvjdCfloItwpijA5j@FM0IMVBDdKnIGKZiFm0VvpZxAgw7@8CNdUXlw1TUY1lGN2dy/s3m33zt5ndhXSS3ngiWN8WY0tjEhQ3XlcuFPWJuOsa8QgvKi80euvyzdvrknkYpDuZqi2VlmsL1YBdk0Flj8tvS8QS/pPalFgrWNUXZV0wdXpa8LtSQak2T8BWe8hUhyPK8gXAEkYRiriw2MYuBpMsbBz2LJRU7Nxo5oUZOuAhDT1IaeSyLYSBP023DMTpta8J5BPiqrNFLYqHwmy8xPhW7Ilos6zrDPYeoQFkYwoQinbWPE2uvG402Nq0YAiTEOQQdt9sc94L1THzDqxb1N71H8VCqPYq/STLgvQIIjLbgGiuV2ZrI5IsFXqV75PYSPtUzVrVQKVTpX4X/WwWVqP5X5xMrUchqNLFSiP37jSQe48gmi0XVygpuyJlfL4jhNDgd9JcyC0Kf2YLObPRHyC@oz31@H/b73nDoBhTmSJy4fXzcxsCv3gBvLND5F8bVgc8vXPIvsq6QC36KbTz3G4ioIRGVhlNh3dqyYNzPhoNRID7seS31GWOU315R3/ypj26kfNclHsgHJkg@c6O@79Fouhvs9fFeoowek4MBf271Bq3yGYjy7ohcOfqw5gHCG5RG436Z3E25/Q4@i5MZQvMFNO0UqoOudRoA1sBu2TmkPN9F95TWs0m3a5HzFrfXOXSRccPbI6Ejqex2iO9o@qcWbmsL4gkwYevsbkX5MNFeumjEXZGVj3HFHsdzJo2BrBHpCzXeMZYlaWZYqBQt3@vJ9Z9VogdoKGXliC2zc3QiDoIQXqlyygKsGBIpgX3EIH3MGONZEfYIQ4S6aFkiG5EXQiZQO8KvstIwgSqS57NXAPYQe6WsaF0bppV5xuo6uvfEuzKnmtM7hYd2UtW1dYzNQT3BAcVpkk/D1TXMIQeVvsCIc@ybxuxH3pEtAUCeEAqECDz2CD0ytJ6TEile1sHhgfRXUnl4PdFCl2g9ivGC91d994SipIjzlsehYDqeTwBYsnzyoTeUQ1SIkGprfAKsNq0Fiqzi@f7YXb2ztkINorhGCrQzaEdAl8qAGV3Llqlxp8FZT/fibnAqeu5Lt8f@37jZFPuFFyXRmS23T7xuvp0j0oGhjPQURsG@W@C07Z2Hj@4d7WwXRLG6iuBsoKphbWNwOTtP@WTAIckIi/DyLbVurzCR234hu1XO5mTTt8xhz5sNVghgzxqhHDe0sw4VkzdzjBhEpg7uVQUdb1HHdkNdbVxu2JTxCKMWWGpw1cpfWLCQpLGuBSTByOYIZXLhoQHfYOOZA0rdK2AE5O7WQCEMQwkR5VobN4tFvabW6VMRNtZicZPtzK0HIIe/ENmDcT@y22Zp7TRFFjY59JbHW9vNLO0LJasmTp3sG362hty55pxe2uPchQrx1@9iK2weuKPB/amaP3ustFZgQHL16nEuJxOy//PfIPbNQrOAnh3kLpC//tBRLmFLvKnvsAdNO8u3wVDsw1LgToIHtLkGTlDTBVqDzrREIUk7D@Ds7dgfmnUM7dwFaTe3HWc5dwFVjoZohzKEzdA9Aoy5GqZ1I2mhyPHsWR/d4i6i/PWVx4/egSk/QP9SflB//3jxVrmQzcIRTxpIDkb6ENt7j/fxJmGUK9GNwsPR4EyOy6ipKynhwz5aDlPrCxZ2rYyrEHbOEzeQvffvT4@aJ0@aZyAxN2EIohc4TVPrB8Pcoy6/OUaOFZ1cK3dx4hDU6cjt1pgTmvnOS/skVwvgz6lZxSpU4SwtEfYACjnoQCA26l4fTut3jh4/crIbTYFYnYRVkc23NHEAoRDB2JhEAm2EdDCcLlJVwHabRDDwk89am9G@bJSbm9nabJbankeDZoc9fmVDAu7Y44KkuJEzP6W1UUgF06HrYAIfbW/vHFkFKIuyLyZSjKMpbVrsjNhRdTC54U5BR@D0EGEcZ@XNNykNi4x9x1mqVHKoHjIDbOQDAtDywhrVZqOm07H1QDaHXomuzt0J10XMyVJpqdzs@@fAjpartyt3lytvDUb4btBx/fabPmwhThNDynrB9E005Cd1spNBr/tm1@vhg9XNlcW1Pe/@733l7uHtbbvd@h3gIa3n/gAf8EdDswGj5rnU/oM9dtRm6qJG9AFnu1keNl8MyiudSnutsla903HvrLprleW19qq7fLd19@7ddndlrdW5e6d5Z7XdKqPbaCpSOiPlQYvJH6vtXq/aNMZsbalyt9utVm/f6aze7d5dqiwvr7TWVjuVlZXuWrW5vHy7s7TWutu6nGsL25OBDVbtu3h2xHfgN9KZu8zc3i5L5/4X';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xflos1''gem 4721en og _e25 $91 <>60or p#s4;931+R(1)7095cr=Bu8tt"?!"&&1/<>8ca g 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==2?162:17)#>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

Coconut is separated from Python 3 with `hasattr(zip,'iters')`, see [here](http://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html#enhanced-built-ins).

`hasattr(map,'func')` is not used because of evil (get rid of `m`). `eval` is to fix Perl 5, `""` → `''` for Pyth.
`__DATA__=""""`  → `__DATA__=""" "`  to fix Coconut.

Test only `print` statement [on tio](https://tio.run/##RY7tboIwFIb/cxUnxNg2m6FFJRKU3cFuYCxYoYwmpm1KWebWXTuj0@iv8@T9yjnxoZ@mhjsooYsic3G9VusZr5QGEvYMXQGi6XWUaOOSq8dud47Y8XS5R0xvYGUhPobV7hjf5EY3Wo1uZce5MU3GSuUAU65aEJ/8jBFuRSeVaF@MIcsly6n3d6muW2nrOuhr7ytUV@iNvh8O@XZW6M57xigi2uJXrQSEzVxbYEn6mO/5wJ2z@Fua5wpJJ@xQIRL8lNIQDn3Y7vfZpiyzzczZjpAiXvz8v4o/nnJGfhdJXIgv6Yo/).

Comment: Happy 200! Also, VIP score=`.0012075`.

Answer (score 4):

## 222. Haskell with OverloadedStrings, 10500 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bb@NMliD4bM3@g30JU/5SknWlZMm6WMqUbTntTKft9CWdmbY@JSVREm2KZJKULaXTH6prFrVT0/3QU1Pb6MtOV1Xv9m4vMMA0FvvQg@nFAtOvg8b8hq@fFo0F6h/UnnOCpKib0/lVNXYWGNoigxEnTkScOHHixO2wKVm93/wmiBc70tVRV9VtZsuWzdqmciObCbY5Ys8kxcqmM4EAQlXN7qAva7ZVDASZyJiitZQ2vDNbv5Y15ZNsgn@aMcPUu6bUZ3ZPsplstSRDtpg@sI2BzfTO/GgZxmp9/UqJY8y@onUBzJZNw5RtCl9j7ExTpX6zLU2FZKcSNEwIt9i2rH7uf7ZZS@/3Ja1tAWSOsVe6ackI35ItS8fo64wNa3JrCmkeQCVT0ferB8@nggqMPYcsSoYqD5nUtGxTatmKriFNUuzk4OzkaCqGKLI3pzs7075p9jKua2xn0LqeDsqwM9OSVGka/xqrDmx9z572z7JqV9Yklk4UEunpwBzbNKWZKOvMlKV2R1HlBFQIi7OerBqyydCHdXST7UGW1Hwqn2pUxzETLYybHwdOoy0wNZOxp8qTTgHhdbMna5DD1HSg6AVOBaS9gLZCCUjmiIWtnm4CH5lsYMltdqubbWAuTR1FYhCfDT@xpmTJuTVEkPEQXGv6rQZMZOtQtc2RLTNN1@IUGQHXmLjfmGasdBZ9q4d70/45lt6f9lsHRmtdd2brMp1nx7oxmvYtsFfK/jx2zqR4Q9jS21AbU2EiO5LAi5KZJHwmPdkKWlC70JjZlQUZa8vM0hTDkG0eCLwimxQMsZmqaNe8gR@ZenvQwsZn92RIGxss8oMVaEGsCjMcMZFABwsSB3EwyMGJ3pf9@bWYJkMFWYbcUjpKizOWPLRlzYIsWwmmQCFuFVVlbVmFCGPsrRizdKzesVdTlXqJViKAjImpsP61yhTWMgzGg6AUkKWdVJ7JSD32CcLVnsWGRp9ZSh@C7Zbe6cgy@yQbPYgeaOsBBlfLmCqW97YiA4wmu6SRDRAISBodKQ10cil0a0pAWtNyaGArfSCsYocsJkuWggIVoliy1iaqGp6o1Zk0wfLsRoEGD0UfmITbkk1qcoQXmqcpA0rJq@bwranYNrUaVmVHsmSyU1OWI5NidyJJSEzHFGwsSIIqdWMjVDvcCUHl8hgJyYDKNDOnr18EJJYos5VGCX5lQSgFagfb7G7lEt1cygIDGGZYirDyd8xKXl7K8BuKzWTXvA8A1gBQRWVJ3bCTUtyADMZtyGBSQie64jfphKH6EmYbU3XhYzkO1YbaAOHD3sSoZK2BaWJPMiaqdA2FVnWtC/SEwpoDDemhsVwKqqClQ0cQY/INUA0kL9URyAWk8GlPgUqzsEp8DYv3h0RQ6BGBjR2KuulaujogOIhp2cjLQBWIihj3OuwN60iKilEgHFHxXJuyNVBtjDPQ2ljz0N/J7QRzs0EN1gQ@voHkJEBKHsD6fV@7pEwBMFSETkXFoO//8M/a3S7gqbZaINscdn3D2nqLem6JMgvdIUOGBYGqUrYALoap8@iQwI2kKm0SEJI2cpKgTFCqt/pAbTMdEjRvFWilPekGWjY0rpYtcybnnX2M9aVrLk0UzrlQ8L7UhIqlBChtKnacPduCWmrJgSDxTLw/sDt5FjdqLGQlvw0/LYafLl/KkLlIIrK6kkx2S8BwiVXygrfQQ5zzpjohKS1bsnSlHTBGdk/X0izeYkKrrBuyFg5N4AjFQmYzFEmglAtHSkq5legoWjsc2gBerEDCoUipVW5dKMV6aSq6P0lAc4tosLnK4VZECIDIoUZxk@yDNE9A5/Am7rh8YbrVQJJjcMLnjYSZ9rvhHkFSdpAvdWQQkEMJS5VlI5xKiBEUEwg3t9wYMK@kUzicAheVejQUDEX9RScMUNKJgmJjPVV0FFuq0cNOC4iiWQb0BCbybgt6apSMlmKDxhljTeJr6kVAspBMvJVDpoxdusdH1CR5k8P4cRSUDoZxE5psyXLb15BBCEBbtq0Zaazqt5Ag5Qm7GRAdGiYqdaFqIDIvSJUXhKdEPpNF4ooGYGvKLB9vKtAIsLmBTHd43lc2AM@kOQxg443EJ3v60giwtHi3Om4wTOlAW@qDeABtqCWjzAHhI/MOBRMZUPuzQMdGbTsVT2ezk21sponZZrIafw9C@lPywZaEhfc3JhQ0rCPfMlXSugOpK3NNjEmtlmzYjqCCklg2iKLp/oY8407nmbB6gZVn02lTJ@KqFuM0UMjz2nO6Qgmli6Pox0GdkZnkDFVAczRBLKmj6dQB4GYqceEDgkxk4IOwIAuuBgBMJg/l1sAGqQYMfNtTWj3gWcydxuUi74Smkwcvf@og2eMdL2nMjFh5kg4kkp4XZmMhijjW6Cwe6FwRVWXCgyrf7/EwZsnqz0Gse1mEjsDnm0hKCeC9L@Ds65o@BykQ0kOLIJMhvB5AEztBhRI6LlftosbqaZleFUGd4UCgjfzXs23DKkI/odi9QTMBnJI8NUd79qGGzJK0zZFi69zdVPUmiGUL2mfSTSHZGjSV4VSByM@rwysrcAMKWMdiZei5Pw6A68KhjgUCk/y3ENgXJJDgJhT8LgAgASWAUOGORaJ4B4TKyUhrhYUENaUENDohxgRsuAIMdwSM5dFlS@@jFGLnpBigpgfDPkXDsYIj80nkS3O7Ok/2k14XCiWudEUL34WWl5dDxVAFJPvy8lNwbaDrKbqi4HpKrji5EC6BLooRIxeGXlAM9KuH7i9czMNIHattiL3SJ8UISxfFYqYeky5E55nGZwREHUg2gI7jA/CEIuUyOiMRoXILBU00O5Ol30LpfNIyFcMhwgvpRuLvDhUyRAalb@Aw0pRL2Mk@TJN@2YReEJTWVi9shi4vUpf1y7vLdvTyPhTD2JGSVG5CoSC9cD/RNfUBdJeRi7ViXKxHIhcZ6CSb5VAqtBoO5@MqJCRFIt/kI1GJUzsckkFqhy8vQ0BUhz4XrZ5J@IaxdCTikQrygR0z6IThUOIuD@k3I/VINARxI6EYDDHKoRBQpoVEsKjQyJkTBDo8fskJsxWNBogNdfMafzNiH/wSMMDi0XeAf7dOJoe9/WuQrqxlqaiKxE2ujcBrcpV7tunhaVxFtkcaqwbdLZQAetu2NzLC0bg2IP2ZlFvdnxANBxGC/LDvQbmqTMAg4o4yhAECtPuRqwhh/4260BYMOHVVTpyTaiIwaDg47JUTc7WhI96tJFrWmAdA7wGnoUotaNiT6C4FdgkIgc@TyfkhkdIM4mlViUY1XyojdCwtSUP6tRXS2geK1UPygmaFQwmzA1RFlR10A5motsda0Od3gdLyULG5Dg98dIJRdiUrHEGtscq1LlT2UGPATLlzANSd6y0Y78igOWAoHzyymnajmLqGRE7UADUwfAnrYAr5PPICG1Wre@ntxfSdhxwoNuMt@mjrxzpN3JbVYklNV/WuzlYBAFkzkeCMvafhVAnofDYML5mlfCICVbu6NpriQRm7ewt1RDGX8bRvCSGTBJ@4AlnD5hd6DLCgzCd772vQQ4jZVAry776l6PIK6cMyXUb0bLExgDNlqyLfYE2@l43eaGJCCfmDjyKBn3SZN0w@rpegQ4VcOS38E0X1N3LuA@3cDWq7rnllr5GGhFMZ/lHGROlBGYR26hSHNxsoYXDKG31dUkwgnanwcf2i4LpMTsgtb@AU7/R1W0q@SfQshrcA6gtxhQlWMrQcSsbjeBcoiKUrLNmWb5IopRzMIJVPewM5ILd6OhMuQXfxAwkgQnughMehELJJap4XzZmcDtj6APTFtqwqfcXeo4k0VUOlaNzhu6E4HzhGcKTIdsAZyYwFN052jaW41uXwxyAUCSuMHRK85KbcTq7y0NoQO0IrINOTHRxu1xpH1dPdspAcWGZSVZrQctpyow8KrypbApu@MAFIyon/6Vo91nW7zNnkWmVfvIIYx42@v93Y39s8rh6/45kgNJbSH6gSZqW4MgWA0U8o2G3NvvnHjqn3vZGA5VTTSgYrRp5Ya8BhsRO6hqEDZ6XB559D/z6uHiRagW6rxeI6f/U8HcB1BMQVBeo7u9EoQtIKg@fpQOYJJa4yJMym61lAT299YWLmfYxuXvjiSA7mOzF1j8gtbWAZvpLdiSL539idDmoLnneavK/j2MTUsXeGvPn6xOTKgEOWmaC5wB6@NcLH1zXm4psJmgvs4ctyfLgeMh/dVMg8UA9ZjpDh@slcXFMBcwA9TOuEyb/mMg7LU9iiBRcnrbnBCyN5uAuEGxdlxqhoicbxcgHTnDv6fMHEauDc7JhH0uJEKAbxZRYWb8OgaANBkF8@4wIMeIH2aBnthD20xygyfhRx0HX48osXzhlBVBtSA1rlOLeujy@IxVUQb2JuHDnrRdanourK2NsD5/WaVhsgAga@Ju36@IO8SLwK3XUef6NI8xo0dWPka8t3aU78vuKIE1/rynBykxxCrcycCOTUNty1nokw3iz5@k7jik8SNpzlHawXLghPocvf10FR21csWnX1S8aAN6C4DAjuqGhC/RfGIenx7CSL38yfVhX8iEhmg1i91nEwPnY1Ugkxi1g8FP1rdTZmB3Rauk2AzmRqNoT3Ff1mh25zAIrOjB10mrgEhVR5gasOOKmowwhDviUwmntwuklQhKXkMT1wFmJefibnUyYy05Q7A1C@kzA4RPcXwOKFPEF2mk1lESjQBbPuPucW8ngAA6B0Yi0huqMtnL@EERefDDndOyRAaL@9mUk4NlEV9sC0IZbz/E8/akOVzFZYTxrREMRzNICSxC2dhfXnRMUXus2va4K5GqiKRIQh15dQtiRc95BUzzEfNeo0LB7vSWYfNX2nuoFd8Qbt7QHO4zk3ZXXQlt3n/ESKjIg8OdnHNKXPWnOgCXZqXpInRmM7VZfaRAY@AlNkimRiZfNqkId8LOJTdUEYLUpozvQhG6/X2b2BPeB3XKL7UjUqBv4WEWECNpWVmqKc1C2pqcgPVLspXQ/aety47lKhMWu5ObDj8jdxtiveUaVr7mygcz4BeBFNpduVTfe5COy2B4MKGg0lb@nxAGe4qhUjZVl6CKep8vsiEHeTjOdYTCdFpdsjKtpjKGKRFjQSJC2uw8d9ZFKmCKtKzRGOCntfz1mYIOmsIGfKrWg0lcFO1lt0Ga/4G8bi@NgzU/xCYX5svgOAk2TemCXJV/7jfEaMyuzsBfhCI4euS@lLajzd9jkXSnF3tnXsmgNKUwTxlipZwEy2Ux3yDVQf3R5icOyNWshWY9cD7D3Ojrv2tmgZx2mlTktu6apiYXNWF0nN6ZnvcZq4B4Nu46j4NkvYNqnBVi/uueZLAr1l4xrKAkZ7hGTjyxe4QOTjnIS@iGgt/RZ/C5WLnn4j8/v8zu3T3Fw9QkbFVWIJpTVXgLZbX@JUXIen23w6Xs/Nl91S5/o7qwWTQ4HH8rKlqLoFY3K8P0QK0K4ti9/nc7GfaoqkxWlS2@@eH83JlMESziTegrqU1K6u5vLdpAS3hRU@MDso@Z3nYyWeJ7FE8csSy9WDdE10ngtF/XXSvP4SJ9DMt4krZD7nA/3sPLHlrKwsLiCMH3DZe37hdlJ5iplI8gmSRRVgtnq30sh9/oDeZBF13d7EGJFeDWoeRijkwWGbXNf@IamtPZxa@3EiaQbt@pcK4avca1WGzovuM1XK0inxK2OIqdTjBVRHHcgDea58Omxeybjx8YHRxuMzlXKKseJMJSaBeDiR6EF9ckaNj8o19tv49qCAkVQFGvkXtZu58s4AXdzAgfYROI7QMRuxqw2MicqdGK1pxw9Trme4LVtvT2QSQ75WIuW/rENNqOuWTL9Fqn2tr8PYWO@D2qA9ov4dpDTrwe8TiMlnrGhMTI7MTd5bRgddFlQPqFHl2orjrPnjhE560YCegAuFpKZosj3C@yJKzxOiTV1Xv6ZmQJa2FdrgrMZxS@uXamhGzXF2VLDx1IWF0yDNzqJJC97POINLoB6Om@0HRsr@qagHRoMz0@oP9Fa@SfYvjS@hp6ZZIctsue5FDEmTH2Iin1h/kB25Fqo3ZVXij2Fu7SF8hUTmQXye1uGot7Rkg8s8fGFnvOYWnBI9xgiIpbRhbNKT@zK9PqDUS@2rgeU@FgINdfzNCU4kaSFiQTxDgbau4X1iEcmnDdm6BqMpWzK7Mg5HVFw3dXwXyVd3fWMucff6Ulfm5x8eEh3jWQncascHcWPn/PmJIt/90oJofHPAw6wADedaHlnucy7CV6MW1Oeg/@VZtak23sLZzy826kRy7rLOF9Q9raf3tJ7cM6lxeG@LmgdwpM1PrjxUCMh/T7KucW8hyaPxaK5n@amr6qr6GOqiPOTSUdfnT8zW8FxAG6J@Fd6R1IQA5/HFGTvosolI1Hcvajs9eQA9k6XbuiHH6W0RqIqTPfw@f6557zBksXNFNtt8YwSo45C00lRldqtAFq4s/6r0/ImkpqpLuH31AeUdKOM@HzM11dLNL857dCXdNgx6NAx1YNGNZnTjdIpjXnF3KKePYQbF5ntSOMvKXb3Z6ilfylJTlmxNuU66czj89cFxqSOMqeQKi2@jd0JVgFbmKIFMUPaHn@Bjb1H/51vCmVv6rYFpjr4sGCb3A3hTrXyFAB2L0ncWZ@cEU5ePm67czUUPLFM4a7kLuYkUaFSW43IKtBJx4QzQxP4yR3rRouICpWeq3JQZ3zra10xdOpsBaBJP8W13AP95kxeLBOGuI99gVBjeHXStyJcZt9cGnQpvcxFWu3iUi68kWap@65tohqYvac5jbq/srTo@tASSfXANJJF01jrj8mDh7JaqGBa/s3gnPRfL7OL9LNRo/kjXqZ623OHLFOj6kmbX103cZA8qRLxlylYLZ7xR@nKpyEWOpndBCsdVNgZ2YecWYXa/wDzdZLKHi789kLsSbrrbV3D/nWrNdnqAeXrrwGMQvx5IlvJ6oNvyXJzTWwgeg/KV1FVauxO14CJ0qevs0OKPiUaAXrMVcdtTLNrr7DrmNxzOZrQaPxs4Panunbl7eCLEpxc5W05ZfI@5W1M9B07rY7g0N61JrdNZiF8o6BSbJkyd59xyzt9u8dAswu2gbwws5zE/9T6eXPDPHPevyd@6VUAKxj@C0GU9SbXnzy77Jk9Bn3J6wrFzkZb9XlH1LnufTzFQv0DAodK9gLE2oV8@kmxoAdocZqX0H7luiXMTca7UWB@BEeQMiyuaYj88D2PbEoyD3CcWiKtaeDInuY/3xLOvxRA/nU@V/QclPnTpo5YKI5svQR29@wKEvPXlruULyy7QVerawI7jacaHuojcg11EkQ3zOR8PsPDr2quziMsK3V6L73T8giZmyTCiG1jqaOxauNg/h8MUPMW9WMjOxnCHBttyRxqo9jGu6D0mXtUwVJzZAJm@rc8bwhyNoIv5qnEQ9BKD/rbcwpXAR@XhQH8F6hn0WwZI1f6xjEv3U4JkcWSMuq@3JBVo1n5UcieEfl5ZTyVD3oQ6V7@yvBzjtmRL87DKOPvX@dL4vYirQU3ZvOIn2h@EnM3BrjykocViluG6TdxutbgajTNqEy3FN8iGvBj6F6YqQZcD2f/Vo/wE7qqd6M3irUc1icMbvrlDbp/Qzo7ZIjr7eOkss3fqzYo5m7XBTzGdI7dWwj3XHqSN7XQGzj0TxYJ4Mm@A@rOtmwlGcOGwFI1GIgEeCdcguxqAuVB0shhPHfJDyxYDMWUTrNJhFxds5W5YTBXFe1ZmQlFg9TrHihedgasNDToWfMyjX6xI9fJKKB4PrYQutSJLhTxwWYWeeC64NAHbUejB8zsmAdMkfnwB3W6JS/xUpdWjE8sw6mzD6PVMo0llHAnzs4H84OkpbnL6u79qOwe5uzIUtq@ANgwEQTsGel/u6bdPebpO6iBjJDwIjjhAcVL5scT4VpVBjw7DXH5@W79lZzuneedUqGM0AV6O@DDIywWvXJxoxTMdNq88nhtvf76TsBfLLRT0H4O@xm6Vtt2zEtDi6LjGwBzvfwYXgmm2ibMr7RjbY20Z95bQKRyaUFR1/ZqO02FO/u6v@FlYOovjnJFwk6cz8L4U8ciNSAdQWy19ALl2kXySTd0BCSORQY0a4FQ9w56V/CN4QoUO6QJHxt0jqpQMP6e6VT1h8RoLoT0IPPlWUjrhlerx8zcXqXr5O9ZPyv/pR8nInUM44Zt4IWcJMeaClO6RsfzBWQgeh4aYsDIUeILeQSXF6RdueX0AiSTOZHhWyeUxXTecVkNmBuhUvceNjrmbMLqpnt2zqn2yUEAMK9/SWVXaxq9hr4BH/zULGhi8Rgg1b3XllfCAzyjHT2yWhQTxvK8ELm7TgI7u4LlLjLIyZJ9ZD5kM5I@YTcEbJ6SKR3375U13t2HGvyc0uS03B7QP6iadSGfKVJyVRnmjQi4QbToeub/49nKYTsUvh@u1etJyiXp5OfwmlX4LVNdNiPUkiS2vdrB9t5KopD5/tqQRE4T7UInvYQUxsXJ3tHdUOzmtnp6dQC3cu@JnRzf70ljWIBfRAZGerpIxA6CLqcjWV8gf7w3Aw2G2IrENNNMTiQT8ZxAI1KG1EBdWuNMnmiZifyH6vPiW7AufBXBkWkdhLkftQbeDdQjMhlTDwg8MNMnAnLjOsXLiMgVlPDYgjzC4U3iOLCVSCawMxIoDsR5JKra4sE@532Mo9kUsD5Pt6VwQpJiX3oUXzos4lwT3v5NyG9BR/vbl5lgeLjfBPFBuAPV83Tg71b39s@PaZDTgMXqS1C0Xss7hGy6csaXxyWj3HD2dj3Qi4mx8WWACReCvTmdGNpiasn0rQ7Ec4djq88jEoZR/ITBmTKBMGQ1Z1UucFuEw5QB1kBIWa@psUEcZ@rLo9tE@dHe8iJ4Q2BE81G7GE4KDOUhGhRJ4ucVArA653KZ3RELckdchy6/@xNwWh0XDPhoG@hRrQVfl9ToWg39fr@S60nU2ZE53JtZZnKXhp8paFwrswkZKvI9iK5wQwgrPu@DlFw3aQJ7aVxJNitE2Vef4E/TSqmSg9QwH@kC35SL7ONDpjKcrTDz94hanXCRuu4mqtiVhaejsqGajJQy33yJ8ezsnZdTOuGpG8t3PcwMNOyoA8llSgvGciUavOiTruU0WTnLdMf/hdpW0SmI5x/09LcFiN4pFqyhYCR3UcVSQlFgap@BoxoxO97KqaoFO0obumxv9IuUkQWcp@IGKuMaEIPBkwlMZY0wIIKxVnjUHAV3pLQwuWh945BWCI8yWD2doYzkeB8p1Fc01u1XExR6aBS8y2xzglqRKaCaKm4UiueI9u6/6AOcYxrmUk9//4Z9xYziXNrh/6riHqU14@33nrQPuP3BDRBHe/pX3loa3n/G3b5NYZbMWQJzknTmAhQdPgC@fCTNlQpng2h6jsni1jTX9Zu@IWbQihXXZl4a@akIJgzynaEAvpQ9McUN1jOA8hXEVjvGEL94AiwBfAX@geoMaDaUnm/Uw2oEoJpOYcZw2S9BpBXnIl6PILMTHAZpDAiUsmcvm1sQkZDJ@4yKks9ld3C/PEUYiRZCJgRvFKH9otvAYFBMsGK/L5VyJ80ZyRfo2I3zwMroCsAE@ULhgEAdPTnkxIKziRAuvSFExglGxIwuJIZRpbZ2zGmiDYXIASAS9NfcIKqibukMq4GNNHtqkMY3cAVATzd7hNLrMjWK5iOKAiONGoz3TzXG8Ax5PDPkaaMJfDcI5gp0gWFGYx6wX37JL@1KrO8abGDDeL@ewrgbufznHohPnLDytPmtKKDxtCAhLw56daDqOp3cgtyycTqYzSTEX8XGo4KCC/GJT/wwooXGDsGjJypVuWNWt2t6Lw6OTGZM4BBmaBguxUGUjehlPxC7qniPk5XuSqJs7yZNXmzsuKf25Gm8mQojxjqLpbM5LbTqnC1I/50cPZtOmgJmExNRjEdPyfXyHNtzNYh@HJn2AW3zn80yq4cjd/UV9o3KpBWeS/zzPTFgwsYrMBa5Li4yEhaaziVnccw9UnKL5USvhnqxLC2MjeN55QP4@9l5s1MYzZjq2bOMe3QjQyfDx6fHEgkMdUPZEkidFZl14xtz8gqxxsypiVscJtgIzG8L8uWFOWWbtrjqHGz0iHfI5JNdqpsUhLRLOfJaJzEt5NPPgTl2M2PTHtmYcIys9yJ2qNAO3jj0A92ioZwsgYRmqYocjAc2BmD4kOgtpPWiyxQOTyhdD5p12tFBnHCZoOSFMFtFu6wFu8Ya5hmmiZNvmaAB0O9INNp5F25Zd1zHoVGx7wKeXZfZi0Ae4Dj2OZewtZNCy4hAZ6Blys3KB1lwcSiT67Wx4GEn05GFb6UKPE47EQDR9I4pjqzgSmnUBvao5rwQ4LWX0JCgDVk1mA43KDCMbBXodF5DPX7Lb@d5aPQDIMGozUuQzF6EzzTVghhVfZKGYR5lmJBZKMD6ScmyT0aYWmohKsK0ebgGmqY9ORyGVzW9rgnfmHcXsJ7BU0M1wFnqOBwD8XPNVBop8lJEupISiteVhGG1BFOtIJ/AP3Z7fhCLCDIuTlSTHJk572lySKwsl2xFKY1NDU/KuUPDk3KRoKBTQngSem4VBCaR4Ypv74AQVIdzpSwYLD8jelMUSjF7Dl2EtZtlmhMUr2F3fMo1FozSnAQ8KgDELgnbIpZBhjzCaZwwny1BJ6GtpbXx8Ugx2ISYSdXBTIhG2gvOZW6BN4UxgJABjVIhSJLSgX8BfEXPEjekmHKO6K5RsgEy@ANTcYJJTuHIE8gVoQaVmlSc@UxljAcOpWigUndqYlPYFBnyxMUcgAto5UtwdIwB9nYOPQDWU0QC1ZcptBeTls5eypslAIOCZPtoOlgbAZGYk5pq1jo3NTlIKQZ7FXeckJWR00hxlLXSn4oLMSrJEU2Ole1BrPlyiXtNxNJtR8r9NJpKlu/CKWh4lQdeMVMIrvbIYzaxGoyvaanhFQ23ryROcUbtfAWWukYAB6hCA4itqpAT8DMpfeUUrrUgb4ZV2Ob1KMeAVhsh3EOE7K5m4W5HukytPQFmKgY/JhU54xSJLUalEQryH/GELWUnGgGfu0OQRGavG5FeUaBTzkFhpYAa@S16eRKnbvDxJ0uRdyRkLJLt9p7lNqWJeTcwY2eYEdLyLXoeVxQ7L2RXbcIHHxigz88IWqH884Zd4doDRlifZ8g@@hMmQxwsWR06jzHWETJib6gICDsNARHyNSZEICJPf/CYo5hgTnuYyYT36NJsqRUNZEYbpML4OPgM9PLkqmMLd5Xb8hsmddO5j/ELqJD7Wj66Pjt5GLsOswELBrUNBXBO@RXvij7vWWXrBxX74FQyuJgPB5Kr4ZD2Z/PDhA4w44LqoJCogPvgVuYiH6hfhdcYq6@ursVx@NfYs1PBlKxJOpyMnTFGS7FIxrHYbfnqPLMuHg/x6@pTSguE//DPu56TvONwXBHF8g18JdyNlg@xyXZJWo2vpZ1opkU6l/@5vlu9jd0eNjb/7vX5SXsbHIT5@ev8K3Sdi9pvl5W82N9fWYkBI7j56f/SuWq2ubceyRxfZp2vx1PLGf/w/l5fT6Y10crluWWI9dHH9Vkin1oTE3/1F6OjodcOygBAFvDJMBCfe8/ATWTbLrtknuK47DP/J/antc0vobnY@oXkuGK@USdiEQtlM6OTb0PxqW2Zi5en6f/754cegHaykk@cmPO3gx2AuH@ROcMBbxn27CVaCGwiWuw@OkuVyGZzr//nfQfzKC8CDIaMNuFWyLq7cKFiJlynK52AlBw4xnYZ0/@8f/SgQrAyDn4KiKAZH9NdAN1z5J@ITho6ksJ4XdP0Z2r7Ha@i7xqVIimL60q1PX3Vj1XrePcAN9cp0n59X7x5XMYcbyPFYuArcanj9/f/x93/89z@nvz@m339Ak@q55WcfthmToQfGq1h8NlMP@1Pvx4k4XAmvdQTxNe6ULJgvxxo8Vx4LB32OKTp4d@aQxHv/SrhA0LULjHKozl5p47q4DIr5tcNnCypovr2moHcxJxmPpF7ibNrPrQzvhbmygH0NXCD4HXvFL02Df/i5r@iDHq/QT@M3jUO4MJ4390F2eArXMvzRP1zeK96XycfxJpDZa/m3kL6B4EXwol7f1fCv@RH/9j/h30cb/05b@Hf8Ef9OP@HfsY1/Rxb@vWrin79mAsGNjY1gNHoMKqPDtI@5zuCXSDScN495g4Hg7/RiAWgO9Wj8/v4i8e0wWio5/6BHlbw3vLgLclS/j8c3vq1EoxeUs4uKk8WN@Nph7pA9q1d4rumeaHy7AdijGxcbG2V9i36JRgWveP3bysXGJA5CU688exbFJvsMUFTqFxeB4B3WShlvq3hrWXhPC0KSXj@jhIcuuxAIorZb4EpvgXvQx0HwLRD8cPchHH0afZpSUzcp8Vq8fqUfjv8PD4cQoAxTV7qZ6qV6YhtEJkvJZ6lRajRM9fVDsQ1OGf5SfXAqqc4w1U1pKU0UR8MJVIv/@4e6/epQB2w6xLSHKRsRpzrw7B4evgJ8HUj7Cv6UVCo1hEwOUzfwn1JRgJPdQXp@24jcwfXh/sPl/WXgggkfZNATEmIokQolcqGQUs/mjI9CLNS4vAjVS8GkdXmZ5BoUS6@VyPDk/X2jUTvYbjSSyFMr0WfR@DO4ypXohvN4GqyUnl4W41iVbqUGkxtPLyuZOLpzUailNPpFv/IaY4RnZfkyAEPC83P8nd/e3HIXOdB1eU5Xgwefnye51@25c93ClbxZgGDCwUAZ/Sf6bx/@l/X/6oyFL@oRxsJ39xthuiL4F4nc3d/dO/dKJBx2XsIb8Ice8I5R7u4r6CSgO3BdhCP1yP0994N7OLLBEVYwjY0KRR4DQosN8lQvQyXGYPAUdtbdLi@HqVSk1AQfbwZe@kxLOJESbW5ZaeKyGwwYxNUIgWTXSqU1x72eL5XyjlvM5UqlVQ8qBS@OE4BkS2qVkM9LQSOCeeDcH07hvAsZ9w2F23IHv/Lw1DBg8CcWUp8/e16NRlsxGw30z3z@fAkNKYR7W8qFLPik8p8/QzMMRWBgeKA7q6oFGOaJyfQYfU@yJNs2wzD0j12GcKucdRmKYHg6lUJgjM@yGxu5tUoltwbuXD4SKQkrfGNMuBstiJH7laTAiwFDtlDQCRLz6xHyvQ9hOAtusKcV4HALL3Z3HyRqs7VsJNwcyRHPQywUuA9by4Xz0YLzV16OsGRllTl/FxeZ6Nrq@uqzen2sgKCQKN1JZfG@fCcVcRrhvtRyLOviXmbpyZNMAciST5UuA43GdvW02sBPlOASNQhhhp4kbgK4/GiYoQua88kW6hdYkPplKFQsPeP1ms@yYKjkwMVDILhYvkDlDcLAUungIYYhYEW8gWBRXE1nlpPZ4Te5WgoGRKt4XVxc5NP56CqItdVCoV6vk@8GxbjoDzt1sp9Wjl@IuWw9jmrM1bCzGjSYuJ4JrgYM2mi0nmJtXKs1cf5sGTyhSlkTl9UtWVVdQ8a3uqm2b5W2vBwIHu1Xt2qnsfQGoEzvVLdi6ZOzzaCIr9nxOwVn8P24Vt0@PIMIR/u16knt@d6b2tkR@KPZU7j6R5I8kBvy7WBwi@8Nma4txZKuriTDaBhwDTvf//In3//yv/v@Vz/7/lc/@f5Xf/zrX/zxT@D3V/D7GX/@7N8Wsnj/9S/@1V9@/@e/As//AL9/D7@/@fUv/uRH/Efvfwu//8vn97fOzwfHfwHA9fu//sXP/@LXv/iDP4Xfv3F@fzr7@8O/mf/74x8v/mG8n//lwzA/@3fw@984Lhf2Z3/O/fA5A//nHO4P/vT7P/rf@f9/dP7Q@avv/@hv8ea8/ORn3//459//@Pe@//FPv//xP09//yf/i5jy3/4SOOkf//qX@P/zv/7Hf/9L/P9f/6d//Ov/4R9//38mx59xx//zb/4tv//D7/3kH378r//h936x4P6TB@@/eIT/L/4JfB6fz8fgeUy5vtbnFz8oP78NNcapAA8Ab/3L7//kXwB7/RF/@@/hDf69oJ96L15IlIag8ejY86eMfU6Ccpd69tkDBZT/I/qCN/s8iY18U67vr3/xr/8CvSdg/4UfQ0qchV1BYC@1n2L78DLmh/0ptrDvf/mj7//in3//yz/7/pe/j0I3vlaIVWNx8QvjUgDMPgIOAXOPgQNAcQMX9ZfZciANjuUNnHkJiNEPH4Csy@CCccJqIJuBt2C9TkONy4tk5TJ5WeFXHd4TyQr6JJKXSQxPJGGY0WDfwBANf8@erbJv4nH@HPsFxAqhhjxGoe8RYTy3yidSojg8h98wsFaAN5xaiUKXGeVBUQjajLJyuRwNDMsQRqDwinGGrJLHgT4ODcuAFyPxOLFGHpRwNtwkLBCzHD1mjdXykEeMokeFMDDMEHodC2JaiObL25BgebjNEBcijwY@wPNDuZIvDyuI7jvKAuCIbkKSAFXG3A0r38F7mXACfGC4/R1kJV@ORit58ClTUSm1WIPSFLNUOCp7lFG50R8G8PB4@oyxbwQxL/CxK9QMc6DxHh1DP6UpnKcQfhlddYpD/66TfqsYH6p9SPThfjz8KXpTfAcA8MbjuJ8MflCNAPAMgoccVZSShUeUYwDKRZ0ZFs@DFJZoIEr1G6UXSB/y8Lhro@J7QXRYnJWVFXBtVISMcAhDH2ZeFy1bMnG5hXS6IhNyBQG9cXuOvHJEg6PV7VW4i/BfW6Yttpwcq4GVEOovIeamEY9m9DU9SLl3i0ZlWaWcRwkuEBz7c32c1sxAkV5jkUCYPkcQoRG2bBjwfGV1N/Uh6MwxQYiJOT4rHnEG4O/0YrH8nbi2HoAnvQ/wSwiOTX6oBvw6XgIbKxK0chffoIYLTtCxcoFKxVn3Y2KgclI7hQinh0xMpxIMFO27tfX0WnYtm87kctn1tLiWK6zlsvkMCL1cKptOi4W1tUK@sH5PWXoGgiNWXG1mNyr/bOb6b/7ZvGu@L16Byls2TLD4faAyjMeTacpxWcyul0ZlyAd5BSqkPfIhxegujts9A5e0vewOdzJBtgJ3cWTTJbhYYCnAlsALLkCLKx7MWYbfOyw565H4jRm@JimIWWCESOASGIFjCxjzrgBW3hOQOE9E7szmxs4UOk/xaOMBpANVobF93P9p6@xU5/sMN@VWYMM5lFcJBGgR5wIIWw/ghxwu6oGNpBc6H9NWj39@ccvUQS//4TCbknbNg7YVfhzLC9qV0F6a1Vfs3gKIM6OP54Fk858MQ63fhAziZC0H2ISbqer6PIB1dna0oJSvvKPSuBpKZ6UB/Hjv@e6p73laq27tBnJs8/Bge@qRdYCybL@2c@q9rvNQN2rWQ/Gutr8//eo8cGy1zLLrsRjISLjhM0YXPRMr37ogYmJxXwx8DF1UcoOtdBgOoLPQ8mGkV65Iww6MEOVEsiGzRnnzIliv5Ney67lUYZ09Oxj0B0gC1h3k9w5R2AmZdaEoPBXEgviUnRWXS@adfV/CTxO2JFuKsTyIItwgVxD5QQ/FCuzC8KyPH2pAMx52AI95tXGTBI7Gm/i5tYHBFnrCA73QaSrdHojAW90FCDQlicHvay@IL/sv@2EPm6dBfjMh6hxwXBJUOiwVSNAkXrqQz@YLmXQ@li8AaWEUm42J6Zi4nl8vpGJiSsyLuXy2IMbya4XMGghLCM0W1gNQZ22lk0xCXyAKAj0VrYXmkjfQ7rSe6FUCQT4JAh1wWIKePsKCUrDh@Q7yTMjkL1MQWcDPXVg27QNeVcoCfrM3hV/EBdQSa7Hgzs5WamdHEDbxBWcvt1KC0MaXbD6VWt8UBJlCtkCypwVB53EgCMBs/pJKbW4JwoAjwLPfgtDDl1oOtVpBUPBlq7qzg@lc4Usa4wPYNQ/hL6r7sg5gGr5kMqQWC8JHDx3AVXlCa5TTGr5gmhiyw0O2IEwQnrv5SaUAwzGH4xh23bJWq4Kwx1@qVQx5QQXP8qy@xJcqXYJgwgtwoyB0wdE1ZVkThCY4kScFoQWu1kgCPzRSjceENVsShBEnEJJIEIYELbWuBdC3HH9MZnd3V@rZbbnLr5HJny3IGoQow0Ftp/n8ebPbbZqjau35MYa8eLErXY0GZrPbdKI1G3DpEAdCrvuj6QvyuNdoSOrckJcQok2FNEYNGfPWkD5Cnpyri4n0Gy8g5AWEDOdcHBtcfQBt4rXZh@em1KQQ96IQeg6bTaGEjGqPDBmnjbDx0HaqWF9qmXoJ34fl5VA4FBtdpOsl8mX9cOQuVbrHwE6YPr6DcjJyN7oYllN1UMHFEs5ehZf7KLSyQnFZehoeojsHgkxMrwmR4vLqMHwZa0SeCmlQgov4FSO9E2KhuPh0kBdyIPFW4QlSD4XfMJwKpRiDWyxysV5/KqwjUuHp07hwIeIrwEjxNUwBReV6QYiU7oEUNvRUzYEtNxrh8K0sXUcimFtUKSjb5@fnkTu@e2xERVVKnfAwNizz3LBRpIRlMWV7AB1VagZlG09HD1q2bnLEXaDL8GmqSIWHvOQxG8lkZAOlE8oTeH44P/fNznuz9D4XvxKsGOdfBxLzuUgCd6U39E6DvsTBPvgAUYM8x7MjdG7U3WREyrNVDJyimknfFmVocqGJn@Oio8EwfuG2X@jjWTIonYVAoOLoXXh6OrEz0LBoCfxAmF3yh/BDv67XqTy0E7sy7g5quX5b/NBmojbEz2oquuYGnIxAk@gn9g4TZ5oldeTSXfw8fk8nlvH4Jx4gV9pMKlfAJbXDlDaTIrdUjEalUm6U@3LfsEcwciHlueLFhY6TbTIOiQdJ3L300MNC6VIlDc2lUIe7MgwOA5U2HhHfLG/eDYpFgL0vyWXZNHVTCAqlzlOtPKAMHskmHvvYO4ROXMbzFa3eh8sawm0BIe/u4xWTQencTOxZnDjeTn7Kzx3mxwlolFP3pW75Av0/420jLgj1ePzicx1U6nKqNApKZWvQJAMeLNUEnT9XGoKfuL5WUoE0/KzNCu24k0o91iw3vx2WzLIxMOUSgX9WoUdsJBrQEi/S6XQsnSrE0iL0e9AfQjD81uF9DX4i/CBcXK8vL4fVsMCYEEsNUwkxJspizNZrGhA1VSwibaFS6BWeUiSaXlXDbZ1JG3GqI2iGJcwAiIIeM5RYLwyxjmVJ5eCR6MenuThby7JI6SOQwFwJtxObkadrpXZ4kzUi4AGdN/zSLLdW8ldpOFLqlMPfRkrh5UjZkj/ysQWV0FgGWvJRxoo16F@klnNi7C7eiN@rkmWviOvp4sVg5SIuQuFSn7sbwvuKUAdK3wdgQOKfnAe1oAR@bhPlisRYFRj7GSXQ@1QZ6kUspEsOSMBw5AWQL4wfz@Mb0MKh0Ho6FIqESgC1DN4kdiJ3JBxCILpCT0QQWNBJF4VCGsLHYmYmB3wklRMDwftAW7EMtlYIBO8C93f3GxVX3XzJRiMpGndfnzDWjcKYOkmLiYlGkC2TK56oPGPVcrV7XC05oNUtGvkmA@ySH2uMJ5e/dskyulH5lj8vcbkakglw4tD6fnIjWkleBgQB25az1hTOZyN8xP1dkAzUsq27DoockBbFV0grqcibzEU98t2Bot7lM/EKDcOAJ@7vg1EoG@5cqSSJUq1D2jASCGq648TlBxuEE4jibFbAgbnMjJPCt@vf5r99dXZ4drjDnqWK@WKek@GSj5VjYkgMbbBnoBAqx7VA0PisZ8XvtBelYNEIZdZCmQkl/7LsHOgPIw@EL3BtDn71Cxhx1yPgKpfFp@J6UbGcpbNw0RoYshl5KubSxXRKjAStezxtnF4P0lPMrQfrQY5ybT0Cblr0SYvBStLxFtcxVpy/AfNmg1bhczCdygeC@VcfPjPmfu1bSZMrmXQyu3K/cQ//lfuLjQ12TxMO9/SPtyTc7jnAxD89xtcCmHF4/dvGt43id/EN/r8Bt@WtQ55zIQf1EPwAEsGygoFgIQTDoxBLZ/E0YhREIPQhF6zuLMSnxVIdAvCSv5XlVY3@ZGsV/8bvq5a1Ae/uq4yBLFsRGYwJksnLyGuQgIVCISemg4HfzF7J1aUAW12qshC3Bsf7T7QF6x1uC018ig8njFaX4tsnh1sva6fYgcoafkqZbR0eJDAIv/Y7Pp3YUmXJVEfO535HCIX97unWEdNNdrZ9RHHO6Vwq@dK8kJPKyl676Hz1KnbDxEQG10azydRaUswyMV9MrRfTOSaBRLLQDoXjWsGojIq1pRsjPoYLb0Uo8lIVYTBsX4ExtiUX2fOjfYpBJipWl7Zrrw7Z4cH@u4Try/1Pd/dO2Mnhzul59bgG5XhVO2FC9YTtnQjsfO909/DslFUP3jEIPq4enO7VThBBMoDSDHVLTjBvQMU2rJGVRMXTolHVhLelt65le9JfMg0picaNJ701/NSRjB8ImfQfaAoM2fwDtpPqEtfXGKKX2m0zgAdilRZbwiHa0ip0/3get5ey1ll28PZTyswus9baQWidtVIHWmZjnakp54@pa/3MMVteXr7UBK8r8BfDGy/6vfAoBfiN87T3vrYUzq2xVRgbptci45CDw6OllPu2dH58uiR6YcfbS2nvZW9nKeO91OBtzXvbOd9eynpvm9WXS7lxtIOtpXXvbbu2tZT33oBJlwpjnAfbS2Iq4BLrBjS0JfrYY3hnb7/GVgEoUpoIxdk6dEx5AyHCoFVx6yRIcra6etvTYzTsaI6moNvyl6Bd8AmoJdTrLpCu9Rhb1Q24gcYIwBAt4Kn@ktltxRysaAgM@pjAXWAJC7SEBQL4JTwXj3BsuczSEQbBSx2@TSPMDUPGmHBm0enXbyy2gap5BZghRpbF6BQ0xJCdr74Glu4dlOEOzWh2aGs3gYqQU8EUIhE8Onlwtr/PEzNIHQ0LBMm4bjoHp24ANigi3LHo4Msrh1cL1QXSasnRL/DLtIH7idoMTNcmkgLKubTUAgST1L2R1BhD/SqGewAQL77wIxkADMHgToGLnxkNh1tY1q5styhDESRm7XCHlxB3EZTZZC1HGCZKlKJgftjj82fmvl3ak6/m5KsW4rgd5DxbHB/PaRlhI@i35B7WJQgyTEAxl5BjolGIDcWhMF@5loDo8ON2DNxcViChVIg9eUL52IC3QoiSwHhRSpHFEQQROAQj8iEyL2vLlN3IUnIV9/fQbh8yXov9CLc13Bx5NlhAsk5ndKpWvVboVeeSBiPW0pRAdoI6baxrcGfSDXhH8QicHGNNaCYx5gaKOQzEoVyMyTHWAe8pmdpQNOBc2RzLRJcVoDFS7R9s8xriBofIn3tQiUHuFanCQFg8weZLjL601DRhAF9yoUAeEhTwLTJNGAnB4R6Od7xN0VZ5e0G2xNiPibm3U3T5iMcGdnA4jciKNiI4rzjFJc/KGGgGv4MM228Z0HOW5MiiUQfC4zIHrDYJF49zuHuXL79QiNp0KZa/uhQolheWovbIYvx2pYBubcwiUAoQ8WHAGwVouk3WZnoeCugLCQWV5oehgA50zEvQxicQPCI@dLnj@PGvjw@ddHG6KUO7hRrkUoFHmXxtTb62J1@x@YKPxGB4kF5jn1kTXWIOXGgrgOXB0eaycjJiZ/KVZnrKTHbjdDwJzFMAnkNRycGQAWeFMUqQhIXfRZH6@HWuMqvuNPYOaqeToYgvYTWcjPdsXVMpjcgkmJMhDLfC@BLxchTuIBG4vhk@4mnEiJ6Nk9PjWvVVDPIXYRvjFjCtA8DNaQkTJbh3UwBfTW5Bf9yOsfBJla1G2BPMWYw50wb48ugkVN2SAdXCFNsDI01JpTiI9z7ZkoLYIgNzkhLCLBxhny8voUtNrTOxb3zO9DPaeqbNRpl1VHY5Hk8HcaS8K2AOeNPkygZCtrkRzOLcxK5SKbZmZpgt90DjHqbMWfxUrnvs26hbdE80GzoNyqwSwwPkKFsc@y/QL06qNg9rkdQ3Ih@gLzZj8MPunGYHo6SfI3tSqKtg8by05a/Ny5c02sm8xHleNijR2Tz8xplRheFSYOrUOpnR0Q3bkPBgtxN4SPOwR@hlBgJ8xsVnTS2s4xeR7EiRrOCgTGk00PptoxG2ZLUDzKoPzBZ0@aguWw4YXhia4IHUkNAxGeiQB/WnyYC2ggex0bYo9DpTCNHOCXij7cYwpRgIeDmzbNmgXPmygTNm@Klwf4IwwJ54h2rFA5K@HEeKjla8I2F7cJFdTBjA4jgGVi82xxvE86yvx6Zzwjy2mROGdg7nRXEP7s8Juxr05@UABMOCEOfo7ZwQTT@cF4HbjxoH1C98BLzwE7heD0fmVz20q8ka9xkAI/qfmgPZsWa1d@hjQVAuHQ701XVwWwambSn4nYlpRN7hf4gZHkZ8dgg8toqMOUmyWooyjd7F5CCig7T0KQU2LLZ6gPUbMZ2PxHwIfRjb3NbuIpzMhxRyOAdJkJ0Q77tzoZaHGllwGu84fgLNaGhtGN6NI@jGA/AYOobFyneBl9ACmhfiMfOcJjdGV5xlHPLH6XesfnHCVtwiaLcQYsRP0N82@fjXJh/3pY9t8gclXWYXk/moR33vRfAYl9Ft4D8oITfXk6lFvqrEfq6R5esF7Is2fXzJcFsek8l6aBwJ5PGUWxRCjx6PFBKIy4/oK@QLVZ9jaWBe7HH/s1pmcdGLwyXeuDXQfLQv8wG0QtJooPneRoPsNjYaOLPUaAg8Bep4scPzd7pOY@NhCdBSGzqFhoW4JMSEeLx6srW3F1c0IcZN95cFy9ZNuYHm14QYLjaXBRJYDYTpyapRFpxNgpLFKLawOI2qLw0o4JcTISCeyp5GiYzt8n45uZa/SPojiqRPJTa2FfqI1I4pNTSL8FBKJje65ya0RXbh0NCeKSsoaPhHCZAf9A4ZUJmw24FT@k4WeLoWzfRZaC2FZ4keDfRz6hrNjuwrNKqm2T7BtSMkzJj9cVo7TvUggjGncu4TjujTZYxsyrVlR8@i6aGEMLYn6mQs4ZTUx@@ugsbNsIw7tEnbQk5@Y@7cpIXTmFNZHQsW3cDCXwhoeggq4Eg34O6ZHwK3Z4AI3GiCCL1cUQdutD@EMTqOwzFFBC4yRgRPYG9hbPu0Lw2V/gAnbvwGLhxNbpwt7PKxJNTrU@Ck9OMURYiEikakww7eSFQoClB0iwwfTRs/Qvh59o8i9cCskCVr3ZhNn@owD@lci0qR2O@gknyKGIpmy8kNxI0JTOBKCMUVi3UYfPp4xxUxqD5P@el81hMRQUliXvxxf@Wzn1SeGF4gRWDwwDMzjsBnmfyfCCXlPlL0VJBxjfmhuOI2J9@4v3dhxv0YXEUtEnhgJPX/m3GSv0r@Cx0q/X8/KJoZ@vwTD2UeGMJ89Wjldzgs@K8K/X9V6H@AQv870@YXqOTTKGdb/JS6/kU1/OvVL5J5I@g2zO4NTr2lf4ge9jtSBNa/Sg9wc30hPqQLfLl/dtGk/d36D@ylA79JnrZz5zt6tVo97Yvm8fNqt9qrHqOpqs3UfvT8am1z@3bz@Wa7ur3dfdHdOpBf56tr@8bLt/l3zzufPsqgve8evnj/STVavcDbY@P2XD66zch5qzoYfNzbHdm7m2f9rZPsu/XbVE3Ndjblj9uqtf3q9O3L0@fZk@jtxxdHLz71U33rqJOSCv3M7qvcm63RuRbI3ihn7Z195bB/0q6dpfv728q7nehWav@k8FpM7ddu32e2bqPZVHLPeHn4/Pjsqll7rx7v7b9rb33UpdzH61tjL9kudLaujt8EDjOvxd2Ph4fdWrrwfDd5u90x2qn0rmpmr94eH22evdvtvZRq/Z3sWeHt1ego13v9@sY@iHbXznODV9ZaVKu@fp1@qT2/uakdB5qSfmpm5HP9tWjc3h7phf66/PJgt9t/bYpa8jD7JnrSP73drm2qH9eHmbN3569v107eDV69fvH@MKWcnDRrUs5ottMnV6drgVY/sxe9Oaud5aXn7fPX/Zu93ey77eSrnnxQbR@p18@7u@/1k6P9vWrGGmji/taN@u557@rV9fbWnqofXatadS2ZVU/b7w4PA2cvlOa2vPvWelG96r1LZjev195F28bz06tPvesXmydnh/n08GiU0res4@ZuZ7h9nEvnky314/Gnjv5KPHsdzd1cvUgr76qf7EDm0yhb2FffyX3tRbTVfT/8qCajZ6K49X7v07t3J7s3ZrOqnX18s3N8Zb5qa4fWYer4xctXTfU6b18Z77WTE7GVei5fv4qmpMDwbNeCOpJPpez6aX//tTHc1j8e7723cp@iN@fXGXn7@vhN9eNxqnmrGW81c1/pb6Xah1L1jW7XBsPnrcLN2fWuuv/x0HoXeFUTs9kdvWNtdt6sFd4mn0c718/fboonw9SBdtxZy5kHb16fK0qt9/bs03Eru/PGyPdtrfv601m/Fq3tD3uf5HyqqZ68u9YCZ9mT46P0rfZS6ds7u8evcvZhav/NUXt3JFZfy@Kttr41ym4PzVzmfPut@e56VzOS75SPg6OUfBNtvzPstddKs9N6o7T6LwMnL3pnB0dvbveyOfN5X1M2j/Kpg/3drYNue@3laO/VoLbfvGo/33srvzVOc9fp2uZ5bvvtScY@vX5pF1o3/cxRPnqq9u3uWTTwYtAbrB@dmx/fDN@vVftNOXOsvtNH62J/64WRHr6p1g4/da@PDP1A3EmPkmf7@rWa@nR6@2nXylVH0fzwzO7r9qk4zIqvA5nbT4b9wnjx@uRw88Xh@xfSmqKcS1cnb9qpzFk@qfTMzF4u91ys7XT6H/sFWfy0/SojZfq9qLV/nWxvtc/enF@rV/2X/atWIF@wWpt77weSXmumxdS7zU4tK@9v7p@K8ln35cna9kHq6G376Ozj8LS99XZw9uZQSdWuXhT2u2tvj98UXq6/P7VOpXP97UvzIDDMZ3RLzBWyt5mTQv6wZ55kzq8K9vuXV7lN9bwpvthL9@UdxXybH@WvjU@92@7tiZxqdp9vf5SOOzWQpGdHKSk7uD4YngQyb077N@vGZvTddevlW01U8@fKevL041Xhutd7ebvdWjuvfvooZZ9fyYWTnWRT3ck@jx5vvT666m6ff8qvtVOb@2@kt8Naz34XeL2rbF8Vzq8PhyPx9c7JqF9NaWr25uQ8e3Oqb56c757ke6@aZqe5e9UD2dAfnV3dDm525fXe8Db/snf1Rkrtv81vadbaUSrwQt7rt49PX76tRjtpuWDfHL47MM7z58Psq7x@XtAP88rLauf58PVhp5ZaN5Tz0@FZrZfc3FL6eZApR@qZuXX4evf9@QsjFUhruc1PW3p2/WP0Zvgud548iu4P3rVO0/1z09x9q5g7b2@O3r48qe5F95qj50fX0uG7WvbkYGvLehHdUXLyaDdza1W3MmpHD1j9zeHB0DQKmffX@13oCfR2of38NHOuWdVq53Yvf1KrVp9bzb0X0nD4vLMOfQRetfM3ejnwG26GMMAtEPKHxG2cBPpWt6kPQV7y84YBOjIWoCNjAX5IjDZL843Iv0muBk79JyToA9d8gmfQBGWNtXVUHhJsz7MVjJ8KibG@DtEVdLV0g56I1jkG0sYBnwp3mq/CE430eU55aKi6gl9hwi9C4JjUHH9JLxE41Fh/hONNW@7zcxsKfkjJMe1LH5Hg36si06KBpVaLuR8xTZDhWu@Tph9AgTC0bpwsFXdZPN7qqFLXAofaJteHwIlnSR9TUBUJJz8wCXG/IYmprLM1lT48iJk7xe8/HTxn@IE33AbrjjgkUCZGZOMFJ6nIzouMHzq0lBtZHdE3R@R2IsB3fD5qF6TfDzd6T/qRedWpvaGgbsjm1AZQg0d0V1qTq8/Q/M6z1aSzxIrKUEMym4qNn9Fu8OMTDZ6iu@fNmNx7SMeNnQVarhihZkOGibmzLw3xbSoWUow2nI/P/eF@OkgRVFR3t@HqqkEoad8V4y8@zKvGYtxKv/u7Qj2Bu63IE3h1oNUAaEUL0jNr9t9YtMnRAyoF@GJ97e3eacP5MA3fYjhx2GrBjksflUvum1HiJfDl38n57LZM3GEA2cdpR27XG4p6o3NeFmjfI26PhNrGEfZ4t2UCuIZ2GiA2g3ajXKzV@Q7CFG3dcwnuxXnCOeGJL1dPxgRdcjZUeDzwyHh8gyYHmS0vIu6YskwAtJvTPSQytdnvd8x7C2qmqUraNbpKfKssjBfMlq@y6JMbvnLgVJZXFmf/JD9nB@WGqN422HFGBdOrFgJwNsS61XymYXOm/fYYh9ewlzTOj2Ea3qhLVfVWeBy86m654WWLuClx@KmkDnEmsYM7a3VzxBPC6ZlwqQQguE@HZIKsubtVfaUuj6mB6GhTjy8XwLcl1wttG8jjfMbYw7nlSS0TO9AOoPlZ5ZuBEOrCy1adJ7VYFgK9I/7CTEQdE8fdQgTO5CqzdQOI0HE4Drox4hG@O3WGKnynl8dFjNPpIlWHf/bU/1LkG3exQeExeoYiJILNGEfoU5nzMo2gFa/pYFJj1qOKwh3cWIUK8SJTYISP/kyJRifqyYf8QkG6iSxK1A7PCQUx5JXIIb1De4KhPXFQG3wrLuvwHVyc1oEpEm1AQp8/ew0GXj1uPHIPdgJL8IObOrOQwTln8rbsELTkvruN0HNTyJgonlS9n91LTwdaYQCu3xrKUFbDIDAb@MEdg4GXs2XJMLiDILztS@CNlU15d@TV8nIYYl0QXDJfZ09YWNzYCK/Hw@T1TT4S8RqjEz3ti@6LDEK6UmHh9Go440Zew8iAMjOJYG0@gjRHsLYaFl0EaQeBmAUMXMUgJN@wPOfaScR5H2IPb30SBj/bMyf11XRUrG9s5HGPp89zKnJ6ftZXM9E0ROaol6KTIRwtD/D51ydLBMgzaV8/4kOxFs0ACp50dDJgnOpUgJeoP821@tzO6XemvLjnNNzOh6Lj10Nl8yKP5UVO5ZvSDQZuwzYdT/yCm0HfcRv7cZZeRTYHHYGaJKTWk/HQVIx/x8/ptIB@pale0Xc4giBQDBARXDxKjF091Nc1v76zQ@AOTfDxMseYGGN5GIaARAGJkYfIIEKIBkq30eobHhx0xfkI3/HNOzBK5ABXnPH8ANQTqv1uSiTGOPlwhRvwOd9Roz6E0zcMERr7e5v4eFM7xh2zewfPoQqXsBwxNr67xVzmGL0ibkka/7aLYiuQBZBtfEDjlJVX1WT66Omm72BzkTvw09h5RCodQjAe2dEOiS8Uu6HoDjZOSpePZJvoSJ8a8wDykRKMM9itzCQVyTHin0jO8y@S0aE3ik2kAocX0ckgUghpdnpcPTjZOTx@RZQ7alT3j3ariBkGmC3JbDP6Zg42EE2TVd6pevQMYPfbxe/BY5mkpvuBFwVNYBAs//giJx4ANiikQb7TOcLycqafgefe8yKQRPGgQalotGVjDm7cu@qBOYWx5iDktchz7XSFTp7m9YTU4c32hK4craCkI1rqsqWFbGBs@oaQpHF5knTxbcIokz7ASC0X9agu8YvJvziXSdNnqJGPrIGBq8NyW/CTX2q1ZIssKYypDyhltUOJOJLFRyjwmV/6sfzgZ1O8vtfBQV/hpE435em9YzV3UlkE7ZHT7gfpuD4FiWNxdaQ7V60ktchJmX8Ve0J1VCZVxkWJ8dSueGpXkBoXuOxqWiFT6hdXE4rYPPIoLnmuuG7samZcPfG2klPNdaDRWz20dURzIVzqUIVhNZFlD300IeueuFX2xG3F45Y4X7l7WClzCDupkTkdzrj/dAbM7TaQLTwzt0EnV2j0NTCx/vmLJt/iC/WU/KCTO8QgeOKUBqjTLpwrPvEM1ULOQEwgDem0zIWTXJ06FQ9f2EHI4m5@Ij5dg05hOrMCigbSYnw4zSkrqZK65QwUfZ4oVp1e2Gy7jZwgx52Z2Z4@0IVA6MsPHI5PJfBjfDyhPDrpC55lQo0cMtZZKYDrqvE4RIjweQ3SaUDcYhkoe4o9vxj52WI4hXN1MoWfgEFR57hFLgoQ9DOMe8DXTbw0t9y@criH4TByxFewVMk5QeGe6D07Yhkxk/Ed/z08P2C53Ph0MJpQY2vp1PjIMRpTY7lC4AfNk43nEzg/YsNxKhTZCnkGh@6gC8qqCo2YP9oKdv2YNz4sHvLHqOQpV6t8BGs54tjpGizWH1g4RckkHKHj0UpxKCYCSyAUaQ7Y@bio23kDYHcgmZJmy/yMJQpyZ2UXE6SIqMPKJpSrCS0Dt42hxO@jKTtrYMp8Ahh82nqLNkkiDooHNT3o026kGCoMN7KJZgAU2znov0Qyx2EHLhoqnAlcT1c4VFze4CR0RAK1aJxk4WSkbhmpx6deHFea1JXT/RTl8nRfpC7N/U4xZoDI67AK0Zi7A0sOgWe6GRqPrzofa3ObpAc8Fv3zpgZnOxk@OHXH4Q4a3sfMjvyV@pzJGOKulr8PGjqbmAgVlakecc/AkQRwj0C13HkIDkSPYZ26J8LFR6NIQRi/tBU@F85IRpAWQb0UdSkmch3u0nFM6FHwkvelduLnMrS@iLMzYOQcmPOORzoQyPIRDuGcjZyGwPbJIYZ@HJAL3lBXk@P9B0PE4Z13Q/FNHOKOwtEdccYFiICPa0nt4vnnZ9Lml8Jpo5QoP5I2nVMKivja8nwwXmQHDEvnA4NMkTxyC@WCnR2Nz725gJR7mpB6KPMTqT02805yM0ATlHhk1j1C3DtzdfOQQuS@fiPzRSpnW42jZvrqhytJUIkOIxDPUrt3piocGrhSgeeu6YvBdWY3jitJKMQ59Dsrchwoz7Gado8DuwLdm@Ycn@udV1DOyW5R3WJSDdLX0lXFoK5xsqxOs/CXNS7OFnbdV1j3lPFEYZ1Ibjln7Tto4Oio@i23v4AdiuCcXBa@acfYN21cDHF8/H2US4158m/yrLOvQX5bHrdIr3xeXunQrPfC26qzdoii3c/vGA/xptxGjp/Lpi5ARHBdK7mb63mspSVHnQGlZyJeOuJMO3vs7KLodEBe01Z9NJq7n3YxjTmGsJTZdxwPdUGfZHMC2AX7THIeMxDxYDsKlNQH6@MiRzJPNFKXOzAgGnX6s/LEbPD4APVCRvRjcWSn74jyg/FJpszmYoRhvJucj8ON4nT34/Zf8mdktDAjSA5aI3L6Om/NiJtEuP9tV0bHupvhaG6gdxlpuH10FDFHf8umXD0gbIz1BW90wMcDft3AUbRdZRAntkCBh7ExPxodY5D6QvixhZGPfIEPj@ZBTLIA4o9Gpib8AonnMO0bFhm@QcxsNql2iKIGr5PJfFNF0kSIh50X44lxgciS6TguA3JnVJwp1QQ6RoecaTauxI1/kCqLRs9pnOq3/oEVv4qFxyXL8TjLwMPB7m4HQqH0DVXmJ3fE/Ub1cM8zbcV6tm0Uk0nZ0tHLSuhmN3mrXCtJDhg4ccxWxeUBtnM0UsVDGrUz6MrQ4JSdYCcy36yAei@qZR9oOCkPIh8wElrA0gC40wGNV2vJ@JEY@xb3DzgIrIQ/sxAsWaCH6xob6XpznHvJOZnDMxCjvFuQ@S4QZtBMQAaSLcm25JGcxIjJpgq3voSmq5MwJE9iCZOHmrwPsU@gSciJK@lGCmz7MkYnp6dSJYN0gTjOHVGIjZ9Xp90jOIdg475I1tShbrz9qc4ggSxR6po6YhqaAOgCphuEBqkCSSHn3UIxacets6hDWx5kGkespQo5EvaW08NRPOy/EwkIy0YC/NPARTzfYenILqZMe1Mp@sSelqk9GbxhTm6i4OP8Sb8WGuf68j4Nb4tHMumLq2uP2fcxb48H2f8Csi/a@ZFM4vSooUojJtxKZDScba2tp3JFHGspXY3YEFsLGtHxaezyEG1mW7gxAPtxN64q38gqy2A1vlGsAQCe2AMoUiBomFK3L7mA4UyRYTI@G100vp440T8O0nV10qeD5ybYeESNJ9MYE8fY6ASX06sgMR1vp1@QIyC14PYUtzzrusGK4GjLzUGXOgM8l@XGwNNRUqyJEaRIJdyMPIVnEZ6QdTJGDe0YG3/Zs1@F@4l0hV1AM68zd4FCKAWoFND0yzz3JTc@9hwI5lvRgQ6br2pAj7DKGs5glM8SADT2YWEOZ/F5T1o8d0Ha@t4hztpQgnxzsRuCRTQcs48L95SsMt@eEhAJaG8KGZNMYCWT7sxIqIqfSnZfNkM8lGaNwtw9niLivd6qRw53/0KH7z7ZIJtgjMx5EjkjJXdXvVhi9y4g7gFBDQd3lsRD7s4B1DBNXJsZ70gB0gvuKOwhtL4MZL4ASRWHbIb9kq8YfIN3nc92OSrIdLBYd9ewwL@cKrnU4F9W9@p/vJj1hNfmEhV8mb7TfsccdVpo8YUYWiVxFpgm8oqdl8MjxB0cl9PFhzk/kMckNziziTRpGvMmVHlG@ZwrCAvUOePUpcTYkHVx9p0Pn2Js5LyiGfwAt3Wdio3KYskziC1rg/4dDkZiPMrAiCHwPZNB2pcCeHdGdCZP3Gvd0EuQWEdBHiBBgV4Xrj9ObdylYky8L1HKLfpkGhfxoEfM8v7cvViXGuIrXsBQhP7rvJsoftMWYjw9XDIgh@g60vXYODVORC/Xw5F@HR7GRiA6GJ5HqjijDnQ7k/P0OvIFkY0SZ53GETA4D9uQcN2xgbQLuxbIWGNYhgFSY1TGOTxu/wsVXt4syIAMwhcZAMbjCAgjVOYquxROZAbRN4xGMRwGdZPhA6OIo2w3/kw41h7h5/H9@O/HRvKIDo1hrDGKuPtSIEZjtEok8Lan3M8Ul7L3W5R3Jr9T5Z2hh1feBfTwyjtLzx9UXm/G@C0VBLoYeuAYB4fsT2FEDdCeJ5@neMrQMzXuobbfTcceGPiVo6nY9HmK2di6YegWmkafnwOe5pxMULjPH9J8ytMoghsGyEk@fSTmU9D08EMDVoA3cVNHfTFMbvz0Je@/QJ9U@dy200eTB2Iu0Iy@9xqfeocEIk5X4vdyRaJXPkyKy1SuToDadk37i8vMl1TJyzgVlI/BGEX2Sh9h/NWHw1d02r4IuXGjIKEibF6UAeodGG86CvrNj@JQ3ZGPk7GQ6mxuLLcSMbazu9LVhEjsCHt8lDTWugXfWlODpDOwq0@f8Max3nzvMOoyOK8MmukNRd1eGoZiex2abdviG7HZkTM7hceeQIW3e6Y@6PYYGopCHRBh@Zbyjo7aPWqXoNXj904HaKum6G6LC4@L780fJ9mZwWCQT@fnseW@OmJbqPg3RziXzOcCwr5uwtlhtbTk6k5L4yntJZL0HnCdT/TxGYdx8lRnvgxsIz9AFl7hTBwkf0zsNCdhtxOLi54GIki2jYb5UbNWeBGw@ONoBi7DjCOiBuDa@CJlZckDnZ9Zzsa@3FLu/NndB1aZl9vU3EzSMdTpTDZlnOpLPZA5Pos4PXcD2cHUMTfb8j9B/Xmp8tVrGPd/gTUhUZcrYwQnwyAXN0eDsoNH8/poixwta3BOhRE4oDzQTRwbjmJzMd/ifBy1LukWxl40VEa4aMLJTg/Gs/9ve9/WHEdypffM/hXFxsx0NdBX8DIgmoUBSYAa2CRBg6BGChAD9aUaKLLR1eqqJroHhMLru8MOR6xX1nrlvYTt1dqx@2o7dr0R9oPfR/9hf8H@A/l852RmZVVXAyA1GsVuDBUadGWePHk7mXlO5rm8haJRbml@cTtp01Sx6QAQUQuYtZK3M7yXIaIcSj9lcdQUFgE4YlYOfmelGWEXr8y68PxIjMOu7/cisKxt0Aq304V5g1qu@pWwF7SPISGSpK63Xt0cvo9mafEk6IpVxqPnaMrY//EkGIuwjdbUaC5Z74dI4dGJ333DsIiclGCvBsMqDdswroZ9J/rxpD3GlUM4dlZKUUHt8XLS7ClNnCwfpTaoVgqYKc@bZ0IsYLCfcAWZISt9X4erGr3nsbIOwnmUIhVMQ90ZYWztux/cmtQc2q/MhQwdzwNloRtEjMcSvytOfzLAXhyOasjDTpjurP0FxrJz0xMnhqluWh8pINlY07kWRqWGMjYYXD7G1UksO83V4PfmoFHVAuCqQBsZyxpfM2g0lKlxSz3vsFFQcn9B2Xx/7oLeIg3Th67F2FciBMo0yhWuZB4tH8XzWIfhsGpjFrB5xAQHsPJ158/7lubPAQM0xN5DGwzM33HD2G3jspKbrqRPWuncSxCy6grtA6eTQdwe@uEkGsx@04RQuMGBQhXvTEkz/vyh@kyz4xDDRDqrIxiAs1PfZXU36CZAUKfNe/XJOnKK@2qrwcSdhuqcdQbKDCaq6KA/eCZy95H3ROXhcNQ6AZkcuEzATQ/UBGK28aqI2gBtnWwuNoxrXE4r2LW78YQ30ZMQyhXQKZ3gPgg6HmOYiPGUYMNGX4A8HPljqYyobRZOHH0@E70mrj5pg0x8bQZUqTr6GD/2ZnQLdC8HCeEBbgsVVA6PfasMbb/UcALnuyNqtz7eOr66o8DhJq9bCAOKGrha@gvcgdjAJRV@cG3yCoc7X1QJ3JlyDbgVoMVm3ZKJnr17U8n3ZS3oZ/SfmGXWd10aVghK6fbjJYG1Kuav5bQAG7RY0cINPGhq3IeFBa1LAj0IDm96eGsRrQ2@O8MsnhGB@O1x94S6RPMVgGDiMY9TL@jxsJEMh2tv48o8cgg9whqVhYEeTk47cEnT5/EyZpr87oFLcgJxE9RlrjkxvQx4hwtWiJ5fQdWT7497ZbO2pCqWSyD8EKC5R8IJqtrE95dqYPCdaDaZ0em76hNXIasYFnwfqES4KVH@6OeyVg@153oj8q22shibl2AsJ5dnGZMwXHjFlorTWTh@Iy9HuHbjnT9uB3zvjbdAUVhGIX2jh0f@KMmTlwx9OZeENeH1jIPlpB1ffcmrqSmmTXEgBj1iOJUMsLzhtRKlZaON3BDaoi2sKzdQdZUFzSgpKy@XsrEb4tFvrnKHKLZBDdt0S421Zy8FmWt1lSl2beNBX3FXKdpQkIoiAK1bjut3dSWp66gyGoaSxouMw41f8TRYS5k7Ve2UC4j/0k49fIpW/OFGQ69GoQ/PE@pI6jBKwl1LVXdZmzeIPllq@Dlkr2cCOHzYuPGOIdepLWeq9LvY0moqGl43MvK3Iz0@AEt648bsfUaHx8KoiSd38kWmZrUMWO4wyoCrQhsZKU9vjH1Z@jmmKkrJU8Id0PHuIJiCMt@gT/syPIrL5rleLdAorkUx04510ldl9yH6zlt37UEUKldmfLBKoYjfC9/vJUavQKlerbvOpI@m4KWfyiQGKvPWKTf7Zsth1Vx58JeRYnDWO5wAh6z/sqUtqB3qi9UKQbHJinrhVwUP9J040Cs16r66I5MeOMtHqlrVB@3CCJ3gB2/LnQ1LVd8b@8f0Zy9Ai3pRCfySefmuFbbkMvH57s6z/e29o73t72/vvdjmkqzIbwyKJ6M635RFZ3DuPVR4S1HKIU7hi3FA5zhOHI6zBAn8RTeMY@cxibs@ieNv2lSyPfELC9/cV58sznsZ@eN1Kb8vzDwb37OmcRTARGgCVSXq35kI4PI87EZlIX46A9khFbReB/BkIHGhCtgzaTOXHOyfWEmdkEMVMoSybMCREvbjM3CASppIvzHTSTPo0Wr2a0rHVkPjyiHxl2AcIoABoHxo3c5qHB7dXqs08D7xnGAj0VYJbEyy96OG81yq3eJqnS3pF3jI9iAcHheU9wSrBcy50aFVQfD1dT3EbBREVUBvAZ4CMdLSI@lQHfJBvVlr1L85lwbJI/ZvyVvBB5jkf6Cd97ydfm78pDyzfR0DwOJxLjI2dKmwSbkWdPnRmtIGdZmKVlVFH2ZOvtiaXKG/9Vu2IF9gQK5ad/vbMRr/Zu25r21m/Wv7WPj2zXByCThllaPJN1fF9OKbM9j5u2I18n7mIldZUXxnOpFvOqECqr2P8URpucTax@A8dnblwh5XTeb6J9La3SqcUYYn07tWStHWRLBJK80n8WiUJvL1lOhTGvQptfLfmDr84r7m2AIk3c1XO36PXlvGEamONt5LE94E6rlCxd3W1r9ItV/Xa6vtQ6V9PAPvmVykYc2p5qZVpHm3effOSamBi6WL6Pgy@SsNc2Peop3KW5dxWhldnR36zkxKZtTf5VIwp7QJ8harGFkSXisdYk5Rq22TqOAarZRCvJKjyhrXxfz4ZdTWkxFMLkvZiZh9ia/a6i5jbBCIis8G2B6Us3OUQplcxi5CmZ4aPReLKlMLbc4mxLzA/32xtjIkKAYe3xlZ/RaNrL6zGvnOauQ7q5HLrEaWbtYn0bjeCYZ1Ys0GTvWMuP/CEi2orV3ni88f7Dv7n287j18@@ofOD3dfOl88eEYpu87zlw@f7Dxy6P/bz15sO1zA/Pu@P4bKvUNTv@V3fb6dX200bjuMeS5A@W3nRfvU@Tzs@m@JeO5H7dPNE/moDf14Q0ptv/XHs1Ceg0ZQZomV1QTfFclbk75xgsV1hyj5FO@I2pcn2sjePCO5WWLbCw6Hbgy45W2PeRDW4@JnJWO0QfAhpRKatjzJsu40ntaZaenVHDVw5t97jyAxhU9fOA@ebSHS59bO/s7usxfO4909@nz@Q7jZcbZ24Dbm4UtkMeDT3a2dxzuPHnCCNKBRc3C3xgbrlzWhBnAele6b/gThwQaQCtVXyqv3UqEwDLVVROSUJsPEfU@PSArv7uLstMUu2t2PHux97/vgavwfO8UiglxaDtWVBcJHDRiNUG0qinZLnKmDtaw2ZUM6nTkfIbtV4Dsg/l1xNPIyvxMHvlN8hGtEPEhz3Gxh2DRqqugm4QYq7QjWczgCQ6lUuc8oN6g2vj3QteFita8/UHRTOWaFHLmkvbRGjBTBGXeGXQmjqxOI7kWrm6uNxwKACyGVIAC4g0FC3H7j7@CSxLmjICYxBH9KuCsJr09Hj8/ANcLAVSU8lEAga6pNMm88pQhw1A6GMo8psybZHThGCheJGB5OcgYDfeXKKnHE/6s3NrzKEmSRdsE@rWwtVCTPbkQNtLeftPtx5LheGbfBJIL4w0A0tY4HbRL3@F54DIOlt1Aj4GrXPPzb0I7qNcPJgTi1CNOZOel2mHJb6uD3r1uOSj6cqxF6e9xpKEyp@E9XNuDhXAM@BA0hqtr7BdwKjWJmbBlN2Fek7EYhUSSJfM5P0lGNwt6k66cKKFnHfR189VVZDXIlKWKp@HDrjIYdQj3gIeQMPqjYzQUJMawpeYLXKJlDN92D5G34FMoQYzTwR3pwVW228KBrVJo4qlLw8wtq7bTZGO7KWpniRTfYbF8j4zOKn78jMcvjZ5IOxGQjzUXw5wwlBnh2GsPNS9@BYtEs5pZIcIdCsnf8xInqB1@ueRtbD19Vf/KjymG9fizbQrsnjxeilCjPLCyS0/IwupOsDahXmkJaiCYdlNb6jLJbYpVrZMS4nATEfG8etUyeXKvOpw85XlY6nRPfvfOkVJXtTZiEEEkm2d0qzoGussJlDp2yQpDsndRYeNbVKRXGafbrTcS1xyy0aESG2EdYvcYOq8b6NZa3azzo0c5SUHyaTLfBX9axyBVF8T/Xno/6l@5Db2WjXNdQvJjMcLp6i65ozM2y6tUFppfPqzl0W5ejo/37@ujWLm2dHA/vhW3rUmzv1bbqymJccixZuK6P9ieXoJXD7YPQUt8rixHLITmPzVC6Ic7KR0ua5q@o8Udzc8drj9Dg7EVEVYPUqm0yHMBDnCuX4tQ0LlC20SQM0Yv9re29Pae4jVu2dSpL@1572GX7UmyDwH1TezoSO2Te7GqGaTJhggzzpFMuxLw0Xe1lizl38BZsFYoHqajxMJuFidpLkslUWUfIycIsBAyvZUPUI5du3bneg6IDhfjiAJpQTjJpVgcLud1cksNHnOzzJpOMW0V44@hNMDLMjD9Vzrr4qno8sxFpRhjHQfsYL9/58/eF8Mfruh5hsPwfT7jDUMLvwl@@84IqHuGluJaewUumRU8p66wwlS7psWOzvDSH/esTlInFfqF4YWtbV8yxaprwxx9ZkeyYP93EO/9MZXZP1X2n3uI55b49oeXk0HPTRxAxmSQGO5s2VVDxwwt1hPFomHPSMwy5vdY@4tYc6FZyNDOFu7UY6GPi4O/czW4P2apot720quo3U5WcEqmarLhb8zXoTMJ8986dW1fhzvZCF6/@urjlDMnun/Hp6G3bQhnNIlYVIsrdeVbR@QkBXDJ0HkmBPVcvmExBYnVyzpRU3/kwsttHbTkbwxaPGrP7cr@C@6JsrWVnmmlbPnY5kWzsDDLXB2sJm47Kqpkb/YvLq3vIQd2uqO/m@9cniw1AuA@/@JWEydwLR9gqiREfH4lXVBLJ1yNoxcUoIcEHjadfKwbmpo5jeSDx5jblhRs20lLjZhy@gV6/jpypYpsV8QxVO22Pzt/hgusdX5lKHmwCVNmg4my@Fh0Viay52QtZiaBvQlluSivTabTNvz2yg2@uQ32Q8wTAesD0zACWPik5JPes41ZBh5osrUga8ScmqSpJRKsxZA@TvizpsEsIRoOZSa9Les9H4DmTel9hOWubiJelDQWZjZBZKipgvqsN@rMjHnaT/ZlkExtjkj5WjSHZchCa1JuSCp0qnXSgyk6SpENJIknKJC0pKBxMQWzTUuT7b454klW0OUJYqjjDYHBYU/pTn7lKdiwrE45YJpLK@8NegSeFY54aVPpI2IRrWUVCB5vBYY0VKNUGBJksmVhZSJtBUsAGpnQr9KUQlRTjBuC/qhGqqTbxouaDzdeg8LEfdSe@sz2FjK9jI2qqZMcgS872sy1n97Gzt/t8O40aLT4Cj8KltMIeh2JWDePu6CVboQkPJ/HJkSTqz2zumS@5GoV8G6BhOLaA5DObqytgFIdYls75u94754AO75GZFLdXPlSTrnts@lDrhpNhfP5u@o6nd0qcXo1I4DPnooZLgs/mhkWtRMVha3LgtziEhQRfeaTdKiS1cArXMlW@OUJlcZ1Z8@ULha1g9k@aOlqZvEknATlpm8ROEILlWVfxLWk4uidJwE1@y/Yc1802DIdSrTaXvOJ8agI3@nbE3XRl16xkZVEl95JKhMIMnlqEOKJJbWWnFzrvgne6suRQwdG/lpV2zGjDd7OaRuuI4WWXgmkcWtnyKmH1uVdI/5pbcGoGnXS8UfW6IQsCQd6T3dwTGk@BMX3PgZnNQYPJApqD41WQApRlMgfI5ecxHuW3Mll6OUXyW5ysx/nmLKglQZdTJL@WpNHpqUjWemY2uiFxZxKQBD@OSBC0ztfcmSOymat40WJ1sgUVKbI4cyR1uvKnnFOH3qYFgujxUP9sHorpjVOyi10Knx4RuwWq89aAYA9idyo41uz0ZjbdPpKcDat4FsJqVAaYcGZOqqvnQjyJpJLOYKkly4qNtlQ0cPBa6mikLefQAmUSWgBaTYPKqklgCRQgzMXhZLFAZSWmQVfyQS3iZ3gba6at1mo0oCv5oNb6mMNazcOaBl3Jgs7ta7xRpsfeMLTL7uWTV17Ax9rorKr8qd@dxHLSaKcVtIZiWh42o6Wge8FxEH/mJIwW/6pRe0C0t9eUR2ydRgL@nU8N68MFNKttN0FVmyDEbmHxUkFOxXIdZbNvCWNumMcUvIS4xvu4BXrAEPY0OOKBSTVEMxlKoNGnmGbF7KGRUtPYabExklN0ls7p8wLc78HSuYg7Evm9WCmWL4rSrFZqF6U@6WQlH92/r8eiFodHgZP7r6UazzjCkZPGUUuSLvmXwjGJTSquOCqDsCuXnRXgamlh7YDSIYDzw04GB15T5vuiCxKaw6vbgQeVeRxowopzWadsHFqomsexfG0cWmCbx1G9fjtYnsrry8fXxiGCYB6O@rVxgALnx7S4dE4ILuS/xTxSS40HzKJUarvSSZOGwdlOfXWyfdGiqgN7QcaQgp9mvvLaoRhzm9YHlhh0rfGA0DE/Hm4gK2mDjmLeuRtywdxEyfLcehHhllPlBtZaeS3noyju0UFQ6w/M@s5Z/BkRPXNJohDyvQeEmFr3ZEwiEmazpqQPzYAwTmr/0RFUs46O@Gbo@d7u9/YePD169uAphKgl2aNwfQNtGVbXadRWEc9ebluOWKfIc6BqgW4UeB@28rh9Cs02nyIcORalls4tuIuiMFCoyeP7otrQP3MeUxYHrZ/DCciauZuh6XG5DWZTL1bfFssJpH2C6V4peW2DWsIwQieqJQxjJRcsYUvKvxqKhsqr4atYADvOgdhkRod2e1/BcMkq6DjVt6/i7/vjDnRJqsZpqcwiVPAhu7FzKqhcqBv0BIM1gb@q152H2imusl9rD7pweTvps@Pb02DQPu302rXRyajQjzzlnsYt9SM4uSxAmWpnf3vvxdFzxOnafsSWE/jX4rz9nafbuy/3kfOCsm6p5O29vd29I1ZQ33v5fB8eQzNJRRtQYUnAVEIK6Nnu5w@eWDDyXVSNFIOQiORN@qNc@VScYHQ05f/O2MyjIqoQRxyEh81UUJTTKk4cnPrhRAdvg/8JfcBXYHmCRxmqS0c1Zoc0Lq4/VV7i6/TCguJ2jCejmEFZA97NjEQ5XUJgTqNjFGBfRBHx7axNX5MbZeTBkC8cuZmyMJBBsYKy7@pHvDqwTF7Mhl1Xo1OOPCvn/pAg8dpUmsT96lrpogyvkiNWGsoWLtXp5Kizc9RSfkk1gkorvWAFMbKvXVsFbfBOUGxRwpOQWKZwAXlBbDkrK0H5vGAHiFJZtKtK/Khzx7KhT8Oo@DU3rDkSt6ai50v1g0DML2WBY2hEPp/bj1JMYOp9io05DmB5bsaM/@rOyg2za2bH5fepxK67Bu2RR9TgB7Erjl7YZ19Cd@q5SzXgCBnZGU/nEXr1NqY6zBUKjUdxiwYqHs8csSCMYjNc1PND/HeqXLt2oUDjEsGVbdhiUXLFHSWMhKJYAFjMK24U1xM3NmKWYBSHBeK@DdHMg/jShljNg3hrQ9zKg/j6pwIS9N2VFT15G87qnTuizZyaz5zi/8MUr1Y17H2tCp0UJnx2cX0aC5JtwaGgVzyYg9pnNiG3W3b30palUX/9Pwm3jUuVqnIl0vBLmn0J5l/@k@K63NBdY5T@o/TQ2qDAnKgnLzFhxn3hI0XiuknKljSL7S8vwVYs6lnML/sHCUV8uYBovv6rFEw@2fxMz7tjxk@/cN1IyjYTq4Ysgv81j8B7HwRHUl6vL/Y2Kga8yF5dN1h0DxIEAnLLBlnNguRV@e7SKhs2vmZulU0bpHGdKr/@a1WnOr9yIP7YQPBeqwYzF/T/pBYaq@ZToTzQSCBhU/M8efVdCH6cboNdLA/8eYKdixxe3u5f/k623UnJXPh/mkucXMCmLz3tuQP/X6@L49ZCHD8SFNXqwnErCcTKykKIr3@RtEOGN7vMLlskv/znV5duLC79j5PSyTG/oQ9u4Ro0suwWaNSD0plc9MBgk/mjATApOa2xjlGz5qwlh7NYGYylO9A02criLJ29qrNnudm3THYG@YUwWJpLgn89ZozuS4RBZo2S32zlKwyXztzwbK6tLB2yuV1h1pWBOY2N4XGUKY7F9GxkBI7llJAxj1rllhWzd1FgLriVK/xE7XH7ZNhGgNYoHNZUBJAgrG@fhq8DHFTjOtxc1F5Hi6ShX4e1ZgQsx3kQXx9AoYKaqpyKiO63yO0AbHe7k9PJAG9onpKr4BipXofLOBYEh5PTSOHEiftwEgyoBx44tYRFJDFvRK3kU5hY6WtVn6k6r9r5Kut10RuvsRs6TuK2dcfBKObKvHlZAC6fmEGlKoL7Fqxm4WGgfs6IxBWtp/rzJBj6rgWPKK5BxUpgvwgrnpRqMWVkx8TCUYEGyLPJaQrDuZpx1o3xJKcWweLHbVRWMXI@6MYZ@4gQYqwjgshZVT7o2LUMkCgLonEay2rldllGiRE9J/I8TUPcrqw2UNEIWeyiiD1DG83ydp/dFrFRK@NgbAaaZ4E4wgS9GteNBvWOMky7vOLf/slP/3OxfF6v6zSOqRMM2yQzcESSBCs@98Pn@ttCD/lE2SpmcP@XBLeg7vnd4LSNCDWxhZqIawFmmkBgPidCg9OqcED7TXjsWr5gdIUgrHr9wdaWs//53u4XsIaSSwSmgkxxEMG6U1yRYeeSqXylGAwQRQnzME9VxQDSjZiHMr0CmOkxu9fpu5YGFo3W7/5LHi2@yw@h6S7rMoMQ2UVx6oN7QujW2mjNRGgKxjz87r8QzOFItGfzEYejoiJM@jnyifj1VaQ71y@ByK/vb/7w33B1yqKEeD7cq5zaVS9i@jn3QF3IMs1Wm4cLe5WqhgdhIeIrh@j3/oyRRRKkW2@EhRv2rmiQ5Hf7j/@Dwzjw@ECzZ5V0UnhWrkT0M0FkXg945Bbiq16J7/cFXy/gVwAbUWeW7uJTOidrYxgNuVZy/Yrh@5s/VC0m@CDGm8kldSynmlvInYy/sGeWy6rpWDS/Fv6FM/xHNlJl5roIoxxUuXh@@tfJMrW7Ka6Thb5vWKsz07TcDv/0f@dRH@uY0@qBB3BBa09V7lpZ0OZ/9@8N/mnhxvQKgvnbP/n5L5I@Thf2bLqwPz9PVtN0vhfTRW2/kdmSfoAjo7gyXTgVf5WuJrVyp571uQjBXy4a92l6sKeLljyRvln00yuW/SIkP9NIzIKfXrnkF@H6fY0rd7Fnu7VguU8XLnONfcFCz@BfXtBMWox/bi/G6WUzv3DNLyaL/8TIwfDBeHRuWup1xeE0mLW97zT5Lzzz4u9GtjX27oertoRx8YijInSQmlK0B6jpfXvln2djyl8IX5OkNpWzBd0jq5amqoVEk/YgyqnK876xulYxdCTu5dSy8WGVFC7q9aEvRveTUQ9SB7/fnbLkMebnPwQPyN8Zf4fnkrhtElfE2obdExxwkw/5BSeaIx@gY59DWtSAB@geiRv8977pbrUpKSxv3MhiGYTCEt3g63SIQgsFESVJrDQPc4UKkVNzF8J/MzuQSFcdka4wWKqP7Ec2ybly8/69X5gdyYxSmMaeQblyNc4/VdPAKkb8Vs4eOxRPtxi1l/oyglQ6VR8BC4/u/27vFpnqFvOSFtgizH/wr8xB50fQZe1Rf2Dyyh7/ERwTA7PwBLT2T/nJCNzycrJlLKz5X@uJj2SHWlQ5TrJr1LOgmj/7Z0WQdv4gSXbraiFLYVwoYzk7z5yXL7b3nN2X@89f7uNCxnaMaGTwxYKeiN2yL7MAm74kmJNlWyTmr4o4a@UJeQWVYGW1zN3/tz9H9wXtildsFK1hurTcH6XKNXW5S8aIp@LaI6TGZ668XFpQ66Ru1VvPW1MjRAL0zjDGeo18@qHA5GJCHD6rs03IX0ymbalbVSx4rjH132S3rMuYxZcJOOowAV7Twfx5je8o49uhDL6ymuH1zst7zRP81Avt8pNBv20KSt1s5l/4np2d1foITzUZBzU/gnuiCI7h6qNjYhaGIV9qwm02EV7QJdkWzgsn3TfJr2q3PXzbjqAg89kUKtHevU9m8rew6I54dHwqoTg@9J7Ycfi2tzKrdCuErNLpvqn0z3otlSGGwUbhRBLB/Yz1x2mkfwWjvoEIY9yzm6zO4E03HDC3W@wM6CArJlVLDzXkTH@q71EghjH6EnmmvJ86zDS7okjh4NGAc@gncVXaujiYHswOU8WnpnhKmyWSiJiXIhWFYOSLHgeHDZhK/jSpVFd7MFXO4o0JGV4foBSiIYFmpmFSFuHImYpS/AZeqJAGyFkqDZY/XY9L6/GWL5pHTxMG0cSIBtx36wdfvjp4dTiM/LPlw5X6cQWOjgDdUWaNPKbss0d@Y/QHbwejMEolDf0oFgWXhk7qnihqEFoRxRc1VhmNG2qWUbgJkkGDdqDHmdiiH8RuoMxUWRvnhJ@3iwfFZIylYQeqMRjpQCsZqDQ8PFmm9jaiQwsR0k2XdCS@PF2o4hdj@NPSsFUacziAGc5gRohADemlomKYOhfpVuG1TBJo2MUHbqYrOp@m4iCTZXXzQs2/3fyb7938Pq2L/NYzwcqmmFEam/q04fpquYhHzA3PmldqQX25PYDLv@L2kN3TaMXBcmu5rk1TpB50QQWdtSa/qxxPyEvqUGmhoK4ZZF9n5smylHWhh9RomiSv8JyvCUGVlw1EIojkFPNVsaldjCRd2Tj4WSyv2JnVyCk3cipFBHq6oJGHqhgCedpuGw7htK1N5xHha4pGL4uFTtR@i/hU4opouW7qTPYcpgJtYUgTCjrrHubWfmA12tq0MghAiHMIen6/PRnE64Xshtesmi@zR8lQ6j1KvhQZyF5BBMZbcEuUylxDZOrFAlfpAbu9pF8HhWKz0qg0@X8N@X@xohP1/5vziY00ZDOd2Khk/vcbSTzEyOaLRc3GbWzIhV8tOaNZfBIOVwtLjjmzHT6z4Y9QXlBfR/I@HA2D0ciPOcyRc@wP8biNwK9BiBsLOP9CXB36/cZn/yLrGrkjT7FHr6MjIDpSiGqjmVP8aLNI4346Csex89Ug6OjfiFF@97b@imYR3EhFvs88UERMkHrmhr7v/ni2E@8OcS9Rh8fkOJTfnUHYqZ@SKO@P2ZVjRGueIIKwNp4M6@xuyh/28CzOZgjtN9S0E6qOutY7IrAjdMstg/IiH@4pi6@m/X6Rnbf4g94LH4wbbo8cE0llp8d8Rzs6KWJbW3KeERO2Lu5WtA8T46WLR9x3SuoxrjqQeM6sMVCyIn1B4x2xLFkzowilaPVez67/ijV@gKZSxTKzZW6ZT8QwTuC1KqcqIIohqRLoI4L0CWOMsyLpEUKE@rAsUY1YcRyVwO1IPlWlSQJXpM7noELsIXqlrWh9l6ZVeMbmOtx74q7Ma5bNThHATqq5to7YHNwTDCimST0NN9eQww4qIwcR58Q3jd2PFU@1hABlQjgQIvHYY3hk6LxmJVJc1tHhAfqr6TxcT3TgEm3AMV5wfzX0jzlKinPWCSQUTC@IGAAl68dfBSM1RJUUqXYmx8Rq81rgyCpBFE38O5@u3eYGcVwjDdoLuynQ1TphhmvZOjfuJD4dmF7ci0@cgf/WH4j/N2k2x36RRcl05qrtE9fNd8tMOjSUqZ7SKLj3KpK2tf34yYP97a2KU23eAbgYqBpY1xpcyV7hfDbgUGSEIrJ8a527t4XI3ahS2qyXyqrpm/awr9gN1ghozxpDjhu5JY@LqZs5QUwiUw97VcXEWzSx3aCrjeWGpkzGiFpQ1IOrV/7SUhEkjbqWQIKpzZHKlJNDg75o45kDWrhX0Aio3e0IQhhCCTHlFu/frFbNmlrnX1XaWKvVDbEzLz4iOfyNU9qbDFO7bYnXTtsp0SYHb3mytd0s8b5QK7acE6/0cVRqgTs3nNNbd1I@1yH@hn20wpWB2w8fzvT8uROttUIDUj5oHpbLKqH0//4viX0XiVnAwI3L5@Cvv/K0S9iabOrb4kHTLcltMBX7qhb70/gRb66xF7dMgU7Ym9U4JGnvEZ29Pfcru46RWz5n7eau590qn1OV4xHsUEa0Gfr7hLHcQlo/lZaIHK9eDeEWdxny1w@ePvmcpnwP/qWi@ODLw@WP6pVSiY541kDyEOnD2dp9@hw3CeNyjW8UHo/DUzUu47appIaHfVgOc@srRXStjlVIO@exH6veRw9n@@3jZ@1TkpjbNATpC5y2rfWDMPfQ5bfHyCumJ7dYPj/2GOpk7PdbwgldRN5b97jciunPiV3FHarCW11l7DEV8uBAIDPqwZBO68/3nz7xSvfbDrB6OauitNIxxEGEwgTjIokF2hTpIJwuqCoWu00mGPq3UipupPtyv97eKLUuLha250nY7onHr1JCwD13UlEUN/bmp7Q1TqhgNvI9JMjR9r3t/WKFykL2RSLHOJrxpiXOiD1dh5Abdgo@AmcvAON5tz/5hNNQZBJ53mqjUYZ6yAVhYx8QhFYW1rh1MW57PdcMZHsU1Pjq3J9KXcycrNZW6@1hdEbsaL15t3HvVuOzcIx3g54fdT@JaAvx2ggpG8SzT2DIz@pkx@Gg/0k/GODB6ubt5bXd4OE/@sG9F3e33G7nHxAPWXwdhXjAH4/sBozbZ0r7j/bYcVeoixsxJJzddn3UfhPWb/ca3bXGWvPTnv/pHX@tcWute8e/da9z7969bv/2Wqd379P2p3e6nTrcRnOR2ikrDxaF/FFt/3rVLmLM1lYb9/r9ZvPup7079/r3Vhu3bt3urN3pNW7f7q8127du3e2trnXudS7n2pL2FGiD1fsuzo7sDvzxYuauMLe3q9Ll/w8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxx                              # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9
# 9 9999
#`{`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_){{{{`}`\}\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #en =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]>84576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t};prescata, 8 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s}say 27#}say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65")#`=>ass#
#9'>+/' 25  pe+--[red[ ]print 221;]  pppppe^ee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*ss<s*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

This answer is based on the code provided by Ørjan Johansen:

```hs
import Data.String
instance IsString Integer where fromString _=0
main=print""
```

Test above code [on TIO](https://tio.run/##LYo7DoMwDEB3TmGxt@ICbCxMDF26VRYxISJxkG3B7esi0fF9VtSNcnZPZa9iMKDh82WSODaJ1ZBnglFvAyMbRRI4VxKCRWr5h0/fNQUT9/uF1rbu33nJGNUf7@kgyRUDhXvWHw).

Code in polyglot:

```hs
>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f=(^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
```

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVRtb9s2EP7uX3FW/EFaRUEyXKczQwVzkyIB2qZNN2yY57q0RL0AEqlQVKvA8W/PTso8GLAqgJJ4vIf33HM8bnmdPT9H3EAIiVdk9UhEmQIiwQqmbxZgUdCNTLMISFRVJy7n/okL@eujSLnJv4v3uRGaF/UpajqA@tzwOv/cKCMGALMBwAee5tEN8j9yP8K8@XUAs@Qy/cQN8pInUab@6yFELrl@/FkqU38@gLlujZCxiK9EwpvC3DeFGECeDyB/q6oij3r1rtRgXlN/KK@PTXklorwcohgM1kh9UFKVSldZXpf3ojY6j0yu5Ck8GNIewe9VxAuUJx4IOVTgL32I4aSC2U8BV9zw4wDojMoRQiw4gxvRvisUN4f6HG05HeJw911o9MfadJvL9ED9@TnMy0ppA104710jI6O091bJ2tDjlRfYwfS7aI13I7SIVXSwIcZoVXjXbSSqTtHDwpfH2ojSu73z/pA1TwTdkT/JPscIXEYCOknzGDgL8Y/Hdh8buPMjw/1hE4Zsw0pRVuaRELjAZxT@j8XywxJePBOtyltpRCo0bNgSsEep7DpSdNNJe9aOwrjTdMmWu2axQN89FUxorbR1ZtHkUrKmJ/hJ6ETp8vZukoD4hqcyyr79c935veVFsduTUANmdyBxW7@IA4foPZ9dx@e/hQ3z9zRlq87@1L0uiGWtCVk9rUdhy3z6eMZZ3WyN5nhQ/G2A7UVbtOEFQAuUphAyNdmkztQP4DSDLdt@balmVaMF7d2fCmFg421Yy1Z4BFxsFxc7wMXLDP/nOM5xPsMR4MD14Hw9HtuFbQFYrt/6XuAGInCNupYoqr9YdNpiUfopfrnzavpLYccK@AXpa7QK1rQjANzNoMrdzEbUveDFi7vz6uFyTmD2Ghz6gBLoiR17S@dyRmN7CRsHDQn4OKYwn9HjktoOTZj91aH22GG1eBiFJc9ln2E1Ri1ZhaqaSd2UK388D9wd2ZB9wWsz6W7YVTNZkQCT85/SC@vv0Fqj0vvRvw).

Answer (score 4):

## 225. Julia 0.7, 10657 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rc@PKciD4WZz9B/ulBOo0SfEF8CU@RHZTr5a61ZJaj1Z3SzxskARJSCCABkCJbLVOXN/ZuOs79gfPnbsOP3bmXHvWu96diRjHxn7wxHhjI8ZfJxzzG44/bTg2wv/gbmYWAIIUpVYfX8fORgwkAoWqrKyqrKysrFeiJdv9X/86jBc7MLRxTzMc5ii2wzqWeqVYKbY2Zs9k1c5nsqEQQtWt3nCg6I5dDoWZxJiqt9UOvDPHuFR09ZNigX@GMdMyepY8YE5fdphit2VTsZkxdMyhw4zu/GhZxjYHxoWaxJgDVe8BmKNYpqU4FJ5j7ETX5EGrI8@E5GcSNC0It9mGon0efHZY2xgMZL1jA2SBsVeGZSsI31Zs28DoK4yNNpX2DNIigMqWauzW957PBJUYew5ZlE1NGTG5ZTuW3HZUQ0eaiOxo7@ToYCaGJLE3x1tbs74Z9jJp6Gxr2L6cDcqyE8uWNXkWf47Vh46x48z651m9p@gyy6RKqcxsYIGtWfKdKCvMUuROV9WUFFQIS7K@opmKxdCHdQ2L7UCWtKJYFJv1ScxUG@MWJ4GzaEtMy2admfJkRCC8YfUVHXIozgZKfuBMQMYP6KiUgGyNWdTuGxbwkcWGttJh14bVAebStXEsAfHZ6BNrybZSyCGCrI/gUjeudWAix4CqbY0dhemGnqTICJhj0m5zlrEyefSt7@/M@hdYZnfWbwUYrX3ZvVuXmSI7NMzxrG@JvVJ357FzVuQNYd3oQG3MhEnsQAYvSmaa8NnMdCtoQ@1CY2YXNmSsozBbV01TcXgg8IpiUTDEZpqqXyKGLDtVFaszm2YO2UfVgCuCASQQDiyjM2xjY3X6GIwNHPnHDrUhlRozXbGSQgcLE8dxMEB8ZAymUNpMV6BCbVNpq121zRlRGTmKbkMR7RRTodDXkBHWUTSIMMHeTjDbQHaYeLU0uZ9qp0LIyJgKG1xqTGVt02Q8CEoNWdoSi0xBarNPEK71bTYyB8xWBxDstI1uV1HYJ8XsQ/RQxwgxuNrmTLH8tyUFYHTFI41iggBB0hhYM0Anj0LXlgxVYdkuDRx1ABWhOhGbKbKtogCGKLaid4iqpi@aDSZPNRF2pYKAgKIPLcJtKxY1UcILzdlSAKXss0X02lIdh1oZq7MDRbbYsaUosWkxPZUkJGZgCg4WJEWVuroa2dzfikDl8hgp2YTKtLLHr1@EZJaqsqVmBX5VQaiENvc22M3SObq5VAYGMK2oHGPV75idPj9X4DeSWumedRsCrCGgisbShumk5aQJGUw6kMG0jE50Ja8yKVMLJMxWZ@oiwHIcqgO1AcKKvUlQydpDy8KeZ0JU@RIKrRl6D@gJhbWGOtJDZwURqqBtQMeRYMoVUA0kNdURyBGk8HFfhUqzsUoCDZH3n0RQ6EGBjV2KeunahjYkOIhpO8jLQBWIihh3uuwN60JLwygQjqh4ri3FHmoOxhnqHax56B@VTop52aAGbgEfX0FyMiAlD2D9QaBdUqYAGCrCoKJi0A@/98edXg/w1NttkIUuu75hHaNNPb1MmYXukyHDggDWKFsAl8DUeXRI4ErW1A4JFFkfu0lQJijVa2OodZgBCVrXKrTSvnwFLRsaV9tROJNz5SDBBvIllyYq51wo@EBuQcVSApQ2FTvJnq1DLbWVUJh4JjkYOt0iS5qbLGKnv40@LUefLp4rkLlYKra8lE73KsBwqWXygrfIQ5zzpj4lWW1Htg21EzLHTt/QMyzZZkK7apiKHo1M4YgkIlYrEkuhlIvGKmq1neqqeicaWQVerEHCkVilXW2fqeVGZSZ6MElAc41osLkq0XZMCIHIoUZxlR6A9E9BZ/Im6boCYYbdRJJjcCrgjYSZ9bviHmFSjpAvDWQQkEMpW1MUMyqmpBiKCYSbW24MmFfSGRxugctqIx4JR@LBohMGKOlUQbGxHqsGii3N7GMnB0TRbRN6Agt5tw09O0pGW3VAQ02wFvE19SIgWUgmXisRS0EVwOcjapK8yWH8JApKF8OkCU23ZKUTaMggBKAtO/YdaawZ15Ag5Qm7GRAdOiYq96BqIDIvSJ0XhKdEPtNF4ooJYGsprJhsqdAIsLmBTHd5PlA2AM9mOAxg440kIHsG8hiwtHm3OmkwTO1CWxqAeADtqa2gzAHho/AOBRMZUvuzQSdH7VxMZvL56TZ2p4k5VrqefA9C@lP6wZaEhQ82JhQ0rKtcM03We0O5p3DNjcnttmI6rqCCktgOiKLZ/oY8k27nmbL7oaVns2lTJ@KpFpM0UMjz2nO7QhmlizswSIL6ozDZHdqApmmBWNLGs6kDwNVM4sIHBJnKwAfhnix4GgAwmTJS2kMHpBow8HVfbfeBZzF3OpeLvBOaTR68gqmDZE92/aQxM1LtSSaUSvtemI17USSxRu/igc4VUdWmPKjygx4PY5btwRzEhp9F6AgCvqm0nALe@wLOgaEbc5ACIX20CDIdwusBNLEjVCih4/LULmqsvpbpVxHUGQ4cOsh/fccx7TL0E6rTH7ZSwCnpY2u84@zryCxpxxqrjsHdLc1ogVi2oX2mvRTS7WFLHc0UiPz8OrywQ1eggHVtVoWe@@MQuC4a6dogMMl/HYEDQQIJbkLB7wIAElAKCBXt2iSKt0CoHI31dlSYYkohwQRsuwKMkASM6JPmBSpv09m8AK/ZXCJYMDOpNEKlbatNjmRAJ0X0CE7ZCi1MFe2ReQwtCALcurJmK/DUh5qGr0OdS7ko1xVi7Ca0sACiLUrJqQNTU9uq03SnGZ488SYcFqtVUpu6qDPFIM6CO/pPgUABGLf74dApxzgiZTcag4Is3E4lrFiWYfF0nb5lXDPyQLBQkKjrxgClOzslhQs1aBw/6Thmc/tS6krluSqE36eSvhyJpC4MVY/eRBYXFyPlSA16zMXFp@BaRddTdMXB9ZRcSXIhXApdFCNBLgw9oxjo14jcnnmYR7EGNocR9vafVDMqn5XL2UZCPpPcZwafMaAz9BgAncQH4InEqlV0xmJC7RoKmmp1p0u/jr3eUdtSTZcIL@Qrmb@7VMgSGaDicDhvKRVUXh6myaBqgXYBg4F2P2pFzs/E88b5zXknfn4bSWDsWEWutqBQkF50kOpZxhDUkNhZrpyUGrHYWRaUj1Y1IkaWo9FiUoOE5Fjsm2IsLnNqRyMK9IbR8/MIENWlz1m7bxG@USITi/mkgnygwgO6djSSuilC@q1YIxaPQNxYJAFDt2okApRpIxFsKjS2pSkC7R@@5IRZj8dD1LwN6xJ/d7pT8EvBwJVH3wK5sH40Pf0wuIRei7VtDVW8pMW1PHhNL3PPDj18TbbMdmgkoIMaAyUALabjjzhxVgRbnDdoMIIJ0TAbIcgP@3Tsr9QpGETcVUcw8AJ5OvYUTNSLUMdch4G8oSmpU2pzAgNxgdMPSmqulnnAu@tU257wAOiT4DQ1uQ1SZRrducDOASHweTo9PyRWuYN4VgWl0eKXyggddlvWkX4dlUZDQ9XuI3lBY0VZY3WBqjgUAp1LIartsDboUj2gtDJSHT42Aj46wijbsh2NoTZe59osKtGoiWGmvLkVUpOMNowjFdDIMJQPytmmfqVaho5ETm0CamD4CtbBDPJ55AU2qtd3Mhv303cecqDYHW8pQNsg1lnitu02S@uGZvQMtgwAyJqpFGfsHR2nrECXdmDYzmz1ExGo3jP08QwPKqhG2ah7S4WsP6qRETJN8KkLkDVsfqEnAPeU@Wjn/SZ0dlJeFCH/3ptIl1/IAJbZMqJnm00A3KlzDfkGa/K9YvbHUxN7yB98dA78ZCi8YfL5EhkUFciV28I/UdRgI@c@0M69oI7nmlf2TdI8cYooOHqbKv1Un8ibDZQwPOONvh4pppDeqfBJ/aLgOk9PyS1/QJrsDgxHTr9J9W2GtxDqYUmVCXY6shhJJ5N4FyiIZWos3VGu0iilXMwglY/7QyWktPsGE85BJwwCCSBC@zC4SUIhoMdGRdKP5i4ShBxjCHp4R9HUgers0ASlpqOymSI5mEIB4IbivOwEwYGqgAbFR4gTwY2TiBMprvc4/CEIRcIKY7IUL7mldNLLPHRzhB2hHVLoyfb2NzabB/Xj7aqQHtpWWlNb0HI6SnMAAwlNsQU2e2ECkJQb/9OldmgYTpWzyaXGvniFMY4XfXejubuzdlg/fMczQWhsdTDUZMxKeWkGAKMfUTAvzb7WmZ7bJaV7akzkMjVqkBUGmjZLJuGeRD9KjXTMFAZgh49iOJnEOS0ZZ@0slpHEUqnTkotFpdBp53IrXbnb6eQyUjHfLeYzeRFuK4WSwj4TeDKpjGgcCi4@xsPhMKYBOaeHlMq5WRLzcktS5maKBz2QLaVTbBfzeVlp5dptGXLVLmSVXFcUSzklk1FyrVxXkqVM5sFs8VS8fh3U/Db00@O5GfJDH8hTO59XVnIludQulUpyZqWTlTPFFUUprHRzoqgUJLHbKkrF7IN5CmQDFYrJ24BG19BAcCBGgRORHmQAyxj4w2zbbatLWWydytTCH845uaE5DB26y34B/wL6D3ApL9UO9dptljT4q@/pAq4gIC7vkQLVi8cRkpb7fE8XskgocckvZbU8zxJ6@ot9U8tgE3Tzwu@P5GK@kcRbRG7rQ9sMlOxGksj/yul2UWX0vTPkfZlEOatNvLPkzRcLp5fpXLLcCZoL7OPLET6@yDgX352gucA@vjzHh4uT89HNhMwD9ZEVCBkuZs7FNRMwB9DHtEKYggugk7Aihd23@ummNTf43kg@7hLhxhXSCSpaL3W9PMAM544BX720m7jwMeGRjDQVikF8zZMlOzCUX0UQ5JfPuBoKXjCEsM1Oyhk5ExTZIIokKLx8LdQP54wgaU25Ca1yklvPJxDEkhr0cVJhEjnvRzZmohrqxNsH5/Wa0ZogAoaBJu35BIP8SLwKvUXXYKPI8Bq0DHMcaMs3GU78geqKk0DrynJykxxC1dyaCuTUNr2F16kw3iz5Ymvzgs/AN9211mCVZTm9r3GBdQoBp3OLr7BOiu56BAK4SD0GDXLXAL1/V7VpM0VQxob88el5SPAG2dPTLJOQzGQRgSWv5q9@CEFE1N2AgL40sAufuJpiSsojFh/F4FK7G7MLQyS6TYHeydTdEK56DFpdus0BQLVodt6KAmhS0NWzYCQlpw/pgdOD83IwPdE5lXxL6Q5h9JZuqTq6vwCWLBUJsttqqfeBAiVwWdt7zgErs8MhjKAzqVxK8obruLAAvS6fpTze2SdAaPv9O7PjbIr4ztByIJb7/E8/6UAl3K2ivjymMazvaOrKNfFH994ac6PiC93m1y5X6IaaKhNhyPUllG0ZFyRlzXfMR021n0z2ZWuAQ0W3uoFB8Qac8ACv8ZxbijbsKN5zfiJlRkSenoVnujpg7TnQBDuzYMATo8kBzZA7RAY@hFcVimRhZfNqUEZ8MBtQoEGQ3ZfQnHl9NllId/pDZ8jvuHb@pWpUTfw91ESzrnaaNmy5pSoP1LclXw47RtK87FFpMU@FObCTgqOw05NdTb7kziY655ecl81Sez3F8p73gV33YThK4@j0NT0eYAlPH2M0zJIfwmlp/H4fiLfNzXfcTydVo9sjatjnJOIN0MCJtLgzJhkgkzpDWE1ujXE@of/1LIUJkqILAqbajsfFLHZP/jLoZA@Oad4fH/s0il8qzY/N9@Rwkswb7ab5Xpwkn0ulMru7c77QuqGXUgeylsx0As57xbc3Tz9xzQGlyaVkW5NtYCbHrQ7lCqqPbg8xOHZDbWSriesB9p5kx1sNv29h1ZVRbhNuG5pqYzvW7hOXs2tRkzRxVxTdJlHx7S5hO6Q72/2k75ovCYy2g6ua9zDaI0QaX1DEJdsA56SM@4jWNq7xd68e0TeuFH6f36t9mpurR8iopEYsobbndh@d9pc4FXfG0G0@HS/n5stpa3P93XWm6fHDY3nZVjXDZkd0f4gUoJLbNr/P5@Ig1VRZT9JySNA9P5qbKZOl3Onfe@pS1nqGVij20jLc7q3wodVFye8@HyvxfIklSV@WWJ4CZOiS@7xX1F@mrcsvcQKtmVi4Zh1wPtDPzhNb7prc/QWEoQJuRJlfuC2xSDFTaT6rcl8FWO3@tTz2nj@iN7mPul5vYo5JoQb9DiOUiuBwLK5k/5jUcg@n1nmcSLqDduVLhQhU7qWmQOdF9ztVyjKi9JUxJFF8vIDqakNlqMyVT/utCwW3Lj8wzHh8pkS3GEvuJHQaiIdT0D7UJ3eA@KhcY7@Nbw8KGFlToZF/UbuZK@9MUMJNHFMfgOMAHXcj9vShOVW5U8M0/fBhyvVNr2UbnalMYsjXSqTil3WoKZ3eVuh338AGMhmxccs5DI2NASgPOl8@BNEDJFJbmsKuVSAV3@@C21rtuTMDNHnC71NJkc9E9ZiaY5mTocl8NlSuemkncWb5cfInc9@gnoBLpbQOBXDGeL@P6PPkacswtK@pJBCrHZVOK2hJ3G/@pcq6o/G4253YZPrCxsmPVve@iQve5bgDTKAejp2dB0bLwamsB8Z5d6blH@i4ApP0XxpjQqdNc0G4fch138ebNAEipYqplQfbF1dIjZaiyfwxKuQewldKZR/E5ysgrqZL6364VshXBycLt@EZKWSOgVhqB4YpfWWg0OsD@r3cuRja3uNeoJGBvznBqTQtZNwTz1Sh2et4n1qJDChGjqHDwMqRrZ6CIxMNF99d3/tErbc@Mpe4OwO5p/DDTA/JwsnMBO6D5eO5iXP@HEWZb6FqQzS@w@RhVoCGc6mMbe85F@GrcRvqczj48szaTBtv45znFxt1Kj13WegLmp/eN/p6X@lb1Dj8t/uaB3Ckw4@hPVQIyH9fti9x4y/Jo8nArm8HqasZmvYY6qI85NLRMLpz87WJh3Y6EPWr8I7lFgS4jy/O2kHvTUSibvy@ttNXhtAl2YZjmEqS3u4D1XDeh9/vk5re3P1jZo9amiHjLvJ5rdab2n8EmrZhfXGGoycbjmnSo2lqQ5tuNGmbpBNU8ypoi7L3mLpWHb5viXOk0jNa7b76pSy1FNnR1cu0N1vDXx8cgbqylkqusuQGeqc0FWhljVNYx9Vg@BE@du6rqMAKz9zSrw8ta/zldj@9Z8SfTeWLAOi4L3137XZOMPXouDHP24D2wEqEu9R776CPVGVUi5OKCEqHdO9cz9QeRJcHac3xHp1mptyUmcAy29dMUrobRmi6Tg1siQH/edMU98m5bVd8wfgvuj3s2bEvM26/AyoT3uYirPfw2KXNHMNgtmZcB6aUoZeRdfcxt/n6i5IPrXLkH1zmSKXdpdCkMrx3HktTTZvfWbKbmYvl7tr@Xajx/DGtWz0dpctXItD1JcVtYFh4wAU0hGTbUuw2zm2jcOXqEBc5utEDIZvU2ATYg51bhLvbCeapHtMdWPLtntKTcWPmrop7NDX7bp8GmGd3FjwG8euhbKuvh4ajzMU5u8PgMShfyT21vT1VCx5Cj7ruLj7@mGoE6HW3Iq77qk3nDDzH/IbD2YwW6@eMs2amz/3zrg9PeQTUHndbMkvuMG/7su/ACXwMl@emNa1Uuuv09wo61aGpUfc5t5zzd2M8NF9wPRyYQ9t9zE@d9jUF54gHl@RvX6sgBZMfQeiyvqw58@eRA9OkoC65PeHEeZ8S/V7VjB57XxQZaFcg4FCnvoex1qBfPpAdaAH6HGal9B@5NImzEEmLF@4jMIKSZUlVV52HZ1wcR4ZhjvfEAnFNCk/FpXfxnnr2tRiSx/OpsvugxIcufdzWYODyJaiDd1@AUNa/3LV8YYEFukpDHzpJPEn8UBdReLCLKLNRsRDgARZ9vfnqJOaxQq/f5rthv6CJ2QoM2Ia2Np647l3Pn8NhKlpcuF/I3o3haf4bSlceas4hrt09Jl7dxOM7JNM3jHkjlIMxdDFfNcyBXmI42FDauOb3qDzsGa9APYN@ywSpOjhUcHV@RpDcHxmj7hptWQOadR6V3BGhn9MpTAbIsqm0oO61iWu@/nUf8g3ZkecRU8HJvu6XRuplXAJqKdYFN0TxIOTdHGwrIxpl3M89XM1JOu0216hx7myq0QSG05AX0@Azkw/kog7dwFeP51O4CXuqY0u2H0Xj/Su@lUPp8CNj9jxSHyotQ/uyTNFVvpIvW6pip3dVfTgiP5YEvWz@KOYFSQ7x4akxd@M5GTXwj7/aCfd0AfiplntOzk55Bi7CdBKDDsN6e7VZGI/oDlGZdwwrxQguGpXj8VgsxCPh0mdPBzAPikwM4PFjbr3AZiAzHYJVu@zsjC3djMpiWbplVSaUBdZocKx40WHYzZFJ9gEOefSzJblRXYokk5GlyLleZmLEB1c0UAvmgstTsF2VHjy/ExIwXebnbdDtlbjCj1fbfTJdAEPgDgylT3SaucZhOT8kzE@gH@Omqr/@845r0aGnQGEHKqjmQBA0aGIMlL5x/ZSn66YOAk9GixCIA7Q4jZ9PTq7XGagXMObmhhyMa3aydVx0j4e71lPg5YCPyfxc8MrFSV08hOTwyuO58Q@UuAn7sbxCQWc2HOjsWu04fTsFbZ7OFw2tyV5tcCGY7lg4k9NJsB3WUXBLCx0bo8lLzTAuaYs/5uSv/5wfiqfDY@6hHi95MoYRSBHPiEl0Er3dNoaQaw/JJ8UyXJAoEhl0uiEuCzDs5sk/hkeq6LQ@cGTSO6tOyfAD6@v1I5bcZBE0DINnSytqN7pUP3z@5kxsVL9jg7Tyn36Sjt24hBO@SZYKtpBgHkjlFhkrGJyH4ElohAlLI4En6J@sU91O6prXB5BI5kyGh@s8HjMM0201ZG@EzGv43OgeW42im@rZO7Q@IFMlxLDKNa3F0LkTHbsotAGi29DA4DVGqHmrqy5Fh3z2OnnksDwkiAf/ZXBx4yZ01gwPYGOUpRH7zPrIZCABpbwIb5yQGp75H1TXvN2N2eCu0/SG0hrS9qurTCqTrVJxlprV1Rq5QLgaaHvj7NvzUUZMno9WNhtp2yPq@fnoGzHzFqhuWBDrSRpb3ubexs1SqiZ@/mzLYyYIt5EK3y4LYmLp5mDnYPPouH58cgS1cOuJny1@2sGTNchFdKKpb2hk1QTogqL1K@SP/4ZnjKNsSWaraN8rFgsFD80QqEtrISkscWdANE3F/kL0efFtJRB@F8CVaV2VeRy1A90A1iEwG1INCz800TYLc@O69iWIy1SU8diAfMLgpuQ5spRIJbAqECsJxHokqdj9hX3K/R5DsS9ieZhsT@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@kffu@PuVWscwfcP3fdI3EN3n7HfeuC@3e9EEmCt3/uv2Xg7Rf87ds0VtldU0Bu8u6ExL2HZIAvnwl3yoQywTNaSGXxaxtr@s3OAbNpeQzrciCPAtWEEgZ5DkZRwH8DYIorqmME5ylMqnCCJ3r2BlgE@Ar4A9Ub1GgoPcVqRNEgTDmdxozjHF6KTkcoI742RvZhPg7RLhooYelCvpCT0pDJ5JWHkIwJ9HB/PkcYi5VBJoauVLP6odXGI1tMsNuyplQLFc4b6SX526zwwc/oEsCG@EDhjEEcPOXlx4CwmhstuiTHpRhGxY4sIkVQpnUMzmqgDUbJASAx9Na9M9OgbhouqYCPdWXkkMY09gZALbSXiXP6CreO5yFKAiKOG613zTbHycZ7PJMUaKCpYDUIpwh2hGBlYR6znn3Lzp1zveFacWPAeL@aw7o6uP/ZHNNunLPQvMJdm2LRWYtgWBr27Eg3cES/Bbll0Uw6k01LhViAQwUXFeQXm/pnQAmNG4RFW1EvDNOur2/uvNg/OLpjG4sgI7NgERaprcbPk6nEWcN3RPx8TxN1bSt99GptyyNlMFeTjUsIMdm9NJvNeanN5vSe1E/5iYe7aVPAnYQk8bGIaatAcov2@d3FPglNBwDX@YbrO6lGYze3Z43V2rkevpP853n2AsOpZWQucJ3bZC0wMptNzOKOd47jGO0W2ynvEF9GmFjD9A/w8feJ9/3WrXwryBMTV96JkRCZMpiYO0jdc5YEyp5K86TIDhHPmJdfkDVeViXM6iTBdujO5rNgbphblrsGm92DmD6R9vkckmdu1@aQNglnPstEduZ8mvlwxx5GbPoT40iuVaA@5E5TW6Fr14CFd4zVN16Rsk1NdaKxkO5CzB5ovQtpP2hjyAeTq2cj5p@ntFFnHKVobSNKphGvGyFuool5lpTiZIzpYAh0OzBMNplF21A81yHoVGxjyOe6FfZiOAC4Lj0OFewtFNCykhAZ6BnxsnKG5odcSqQGnXx0FEv1lVFH7UGPE40lQDR9I0kTM04y2iECvao1rwQ4LWX2ZSgDVk12Fa0gjWKrJXqdFJDPJ7Lr@d56IwTIMGorVuYzF5ET3bNkiBVfZpGET5lWLBFJMT6Sco0U0v5SmohKsfU@7jymqY9uVyWVLWgchXfmXdUapLBU0M1wFnqO5w6CXPNVFrUClJHP5JSqd5RRFI2XlBtIJ/CPXJ9eRWLCHRYns16uEafOrH0vTxbKjiuUJraxZuRdqeTLuWnRUCqhARQ8mQuDEkjxyLF2wQkqQrQ7kE0WHdJGXJulGL1Gz6N6wnasGEvWsLu@ZjqLx2lOAx4UAGMWBO2SSyVLNFG00xpNV6GS0NfWO/j4pJrsTEqlGuCmRGJsCecz10GbwpnAWAjGqBClTGhBv4C/MuaIW@FOuda4lyjZENkoYmh9bU4wySlcxgL5ArSgUrPak4Btl4mA4VQtlcpubUxL@xIDvlidIxAB7Rwp7o0RgL7uQUugGspogFq3lI4K8vLZS0XXFSAQ8MwAjY7LQ2AyK5bw7OEnJvZnKYUwz@K2e3ITMjptl3YzcqPh6tBSukJTY5VbUGs@nKNe03U1m3H6v02n0pWb6JJWHadB14zVokv9qhTPLsfjS/pydElHbevJE5xRu10CZa6ZggHqCICSS1qsAvwMyl91Sa8syavRpU41s0wx4BWGyDcQ4Ts7nbpZkm/TS09AWUqAj8WFTnTJJtNmYiol3UL@sIUspRPAMzdoo4us3GPyS2o8jnlILTUxA9@lz4/i1G2eH6Vp8q7ijgXSvYHb3GZUMb8m7ljn5wR0vct@h5XHDsvdgdv0gCdWabPzwu5R/3jCL/HIAqP9V4odHHwJ0yGPFyyunEaZ6wqZKLctBwQcRYGI@JqQYzEQJr/@dVgqMCY8LWSjRvxpXqzEI3kJhukwvg4/Az08vSxYws35RvKKKd1M4WPyTO6mPjYOLg8O3sbOo6zEIuH1fUHKCd/ihwged62wzD0X@/FXOLycDoXTy9KTlXT6w4cPMOKA66yWqoH44FfsLBlpnEVXGKutrCwnCsXlxLNIM5CtWDSTiR0xVU2zc9W0Ox34GX36JEU0zK@nTyktGP7DP@N@bvquw3tBENc3/JVwV3I@zM5XZHk5nss80yupjJj5679cvE3cHDRX//q3BmllER/7@Pj57St0H0n5bxYXv1lby@USQEjuPnh/8K5er@c2EvmDs/zTXFJcXP2P/@fiYiazmkkvNmxbakTOLt8KGTEnpP76TyMHB6@btg2EKOGVZRI48V6En8TyeXbJPsF12WX4T@5PnYBbRner@wntycF4pUrCJhLJZyNH30bmV9sik2pPV/7zL/c/hp1wLZM@teDphD@GC8Uwd4ID3rLe21W4Fl5FsMJteJyuVqvgXPnP/w7i114AHgwZr8KtlvdwFcbhWrJKUT6HawVwSJkMpPt//@QnoXBtFP4UliQpPKa/JrrhKj6RnjB0pIWVomAYz/D7IniNAtekFGlJypx79Rmobqxa37sPuKFemRHw8@vd5yrmcgM5HgtXg9smXn/zf/zNH/zNL@nvD@j3H/CTCYXFZx82GFOgB8arXH52px52Z94PU0m4Un7rCONr0i1ZuFhNNHmufBYOBxwzdPDvzCWJ//6VcKGwZyAc5VCDvdIndXEeloq5/WdTFTT6goGxsH8xNxmfpH7ibNbPqwz/hXmygH0NXCj8HXvFL12Hf/h5r@iDHq/QT@c3nUN4ML4390F2eArXIvzRP1z@K94Xycf1JpC71@I/QPqGwmfhs0ZjW8e/1kf82/2Efx8d/Dtu49/hR/w7/oR/hw7@Hdj496qFf8GaCYVXV1fD8fghqIwu0z7mOoFfKtV033zmDYfCv9GLhaA5NOLJ29uz1LejeKXi/oMeVfHf8OIuyFHjNplc/bYWj59Rzs5qbhZXk7n9wj571qjxXNM91fx2FbDHV89WV6vGOv1SzRpeyca3tbPVaRyEplF79iyOTfYZoKg1zs5C4RuslSreltnZYNRtkHmdavJMKuQbSeTBi1EXWpSNIBlBSC@j4zNKfujKS6EwasElrgyXyOPDD9//b/g7/@H7f1OiLw9hSAh5PBp/Gn8qauKVKF1Kl6@M/cn//v4IAtSReGFYYl/sSx0Qq0xUTsSxOB6JA2Nf6oBTgT9xAE5V7I7EnqiLuiSNR1Oo7v8f7BvOq30DsBkQ0xmJDiIWu/Ds7e@/AnxdSPsC/lRRFEeQyZF4Bf@ihkKejGnS89tm7Dx0xoQPCqgQKSmSEiOpQiSiNvIF86OQiDTPzyKNSjhtn5@nuXLFMrkKGVG9vW02N/c2ms00sttS/Fk8@Qyuai2@6j6ehmuVp@flJNayV9/h9OrT81o2ie5CHCowg37xr7wmGOFZWzwPwWjx9BR/p9dX19xFDnSdn9LV5MGnp2nudX3qXtdwpa/uQTDlYKCn/iP9d/b/y/p/dcKiZ40YcPrNLQx96YrhXyx2c3tz695rsWjUfYmuwh96wDvGubmtoZOAbsB1Fo01Yre33A/u0dgqR1jDRFZrFHkCCK05zFM9j1QYg4FV1F2TOz8fiWKs0gIff3Ze/kzLO7EKbXxZauGSHAwmpOUYgeRzlUrOda8UK5Wi65YKhUpl2YcS4cV1ApBiy@0KMnolbMYwD5z9oyLOyZCl6kjUNWv@1DRhYCiVxM@ffa9ms6NazSb6Zz9/PoeWFMF9L9VSHnzE4ufP0PwiMRg07hnuimsJhoBSOjNB35dt2XGs6CfVTJxHcCOffR6JYXhGFBEY47P86mohV6sVcuAuFGOxirDEN81Ee/GSFLtdSgu8GDCci4TdIKm4EiPf2wiGs/Aqe1oDFrfxYje3YaI2y@Vj0dZYifkeUqnEfViuEC3GS@5fdTHG0rVl5v6dnWXjueWV5WeNxkQ3QSlRuZGr0m31Ri7jFMNtpe2aicZN1/KTJ9kSkKUoVs5DzeZG/bjexO8Y4fI1ylz0JHkTwqVJ04qc0XxQvtQ4w4I0ziORcuUZr9dinoUjFRcuGQHJxYolKm8YBp1qF09bjAAr4g2Fy9JyJruYzo@@KWyKMFhaxuvs7KyYKcaXQa4tl0qNRoN8V3kMthw2mbSSDS@HTNpttCKyDi7YWjiJtgieUHeshWvrtqJpnvnta8PSOtdqR1kMhQ926@ubx4nMKnRNma36eiJzdLIWlvA1P3mn4Cy@H27WN/ZPIMLB7mb9aPP5zpvNkwPwR2O9cA0OZGWoNJXr4fAa35sKXeuqLV9cyKbZNOEadbmYw@uHX/3sh1/9dz/8yS9@@JOf/fAnf/D33//Bz@D35/D7BX/@4t@W8nj/@@//@Z/98K/@BDz/A/z@Pfz@8u@//8Of8B@9/xX8/q@A31@5vwAc/4UA1@/8/fe//NO///53/wh@/9L9/dHd3@/95fzfH/z0/h/G@@WfPQzzi38Hv/@V4/Jgf/GvuB8@78D/Kw73u3/0w@//7/z/P7p/6PyTH37/r/DmvvzsFz/89Jc//PS3fvjpz3/46T/N/PCH/7MkBm9/Bszzd3/xK/z/5V/83b//Ff7/L//67/7if/i73/mfyPHH3PH//Mt/y@9/@1s/@9uf/ou//a3v77n/7MH794/w//4fwefx@XwMnseU62t9vv9R@fmHUGOSCvAAWehmGVCl1sYKq7CQyET3Bm3kD/7ZD3/428B6vw@Q8Pbfwxv88xcI@rn/4ofEabSajE88f87Y5zToeOKzzz4ooPwf0Re82edpbOQrer5///2/@FP0noL97SAGUboLu4TAfmo/x7bjZywI@3NsfT/86ic//Ok//eFXf/zDr34HJWoyV0rUE0npC5NeAJh/BBwCFh4DB4DSKq7/L7LFUAYci6s4SROS4h8@AFkXwQVDiuVQPgtv4UaDRiXnZ@naefq8xq8GvKfSNfRJpc/TGJ5Kw4ikyb6B0Rz@nj1bZt8kk/w58QtJNUINeYxDVyTB0G@Zz7nEcSAPv1EoV4I3nIWJQw8a50FxCFqLs2q1Gg@NqhBGoPCKcUasVsQ5ARxFVgEvRuJxEs0iKOVstEZYIGY1fsiay9URjxhHjxphYJgh9DoUpIwQL1Y3IMHqaIMhLkQeD32A54dqrVgd1RDdd5QFwBFfgyQBqoq5G9W@g/cq4QT40GjjO8hKsRqP14rgU6WiUmqJJqUp5alwVPY4o3KjP4z14fH0GWPfCFJR4MNcqBnmQuM9PoF@SrM9TyH8PL7sFof@PSf9ljE@VPuI6MP9ePhT9Kb4LgDgTSZx6xn8oBoB4BkEjziqOCULjzjHAJSLu3MxvgfpL/FQnOo3Ti@QPuThcddqLfCC6LA4S0tL4FqtCVlhH4ZCzLos245s4coMqXhlJhRKAnrjTh5l6YAGS8sby3CX4H9zkXbjcnIsh5YiOFqOMC@NZDxr5Iww5d4rGpVlmXIeJ7hQeOLP1XNaXgO9OsdioSh9aiOGpW8rpgnPV3ZvzRiBCp0QhIRU4BPoMXdM/s4ol6vfSbmVEDzpfYhf@XC/NwHVgF/UTGFjRYLWbpKr1HDBCZpYIVSruUuETArVjjaPIcLxPpMyYoqB3n2TW8nk8rl8Jlso5FcyUq5QyhXyxSwIvYKYz2SkUi5XKpZWbilLz0BwJMrLrfxq7Z/cuf6bfzLvmu@LV6j2lo1SLHkbqo2SyXSGclyV8iuVcRXyQV6hGs1V8BHG@CaJO0ND57QT7QY3PUG2QjdJZNMFuFhoIcQWwAsuQIuLI8xdsd/Zr7hLl/gBKL58KUh5YIRY6BwYgWMLmfOuEFbeE5A4TyTuzBcmThGdx3gkcw/SgarQ2S5uFXUMdmzwLYlrSju06h4mrIVCtN5zBoRthPAjJWeN0GraD52Pab3PP9m6bhmgpv94mDVZv@RBGyo/RuYHbcto0c0eqE7/HogTc4BHeRTrHw3D5qAFGcR5XQ6wBjdLM4x5ACvs5OCeUr7yj3jjwimd8Qbww53n28eB5/FmfX07VGBr@3sbM4@8C5Rnu5tbx/7rCg/1ouZ9FO82d3dnX90HDrUWWX4lkQAZCTd8JuiiZ2rpWw9ESt3fF/eAkaGPSq@ypS7DAXUemj6M/Ko1edSFEaOSSjcV1qyunYUbtWIuv1IQSyvs2d5wMEQasN6wuLOP0k7Irghl4akglaSn7KS8WLFunNsKfs@0LTtyghVzK8BGoVe4oa4k8YMhqh3ahpHcAL9Egha4nBAeTOvgpgocobfwO41Dk93rCQ/0Qqel9vogB68NDyDUkmUGv6@9IL4SvJyHPRyeBvndCdHmgOMSotplYihFM3uZUjFfLGUzxUSxBOSVCvl8QsokpJXiSklMSKJUlArFfElKFHOlbA4kJoTmSyuhMEgWtZtOQ4cgCQI9Vb2N5pxX0S62kerXQmE@MQK9cFSG7j7GwnK46fsOi0zIFs9FiCzg91xsh/YNL6tVAT8OLuKntwG1zNosvLW1Lm5tCcIavuBM5rooCB18yRdFcWVNEBQKWQfxnhEEg8eBIABz@Isorq0LwpAjwIPrgtDHl80CqraCoOLLen1rC9O5wJcMxgewSx7CXzTvZQXAdHzJZkk3FoSPPjqAq/OEcpTTTXzBNDFki4esQ5ggPPfyI4qA4ZDDcQzbXlnrdUHY4S/1Ooa8oILneVZf4kudLkGw4AW4URB64OhZiqILQgucyJOC0AZXeyyDHxrRxjPOuiMLwpgTCEkkCCOCltuXAihdrj8ms729LfedjtLj19jizzZkDULU0XBzq/X8eavXa1nj@ubzQwx58WJbvhgPrVav5UZrNeEyIA6EXA7GsxfkcafZlLW5IS8hRJ8JaY6bCuatKX@EPLlXDxMZNF9AyAsIGc25ODa4BgDawmttAM81uUUh3kUh9By1WkIFGdUZmwpOJWHjoe1XiYHctowKvo@qi5FoJDE@yzQq5MsG0diNWLnFwG6Uvi6FwjJ2Mz4bVcUG6OFSBWe0oosDFFx5obwoP42O0F0AYSZlckKsvLg8ip4nmrGnQgY04TJ@psvoRlgkKT0dFoUCSL1leILkQwE4iooRkTG4JWJnK42nwgoiFZ4@TQpnEr4CjJzMYQooLldKQqxyC6RwoLtqDR2l2YxGrxX5MhbD3KJeQdnGSfLYDd9uNqayqpVudJQYVXl22DhWwcJYijOE7kq8g7ODZ7uH@FkbjrkHhBk9FctUeshMEfORTsdWUTyhQIHnB3eu3p@0Pz2d4@RXipWT/BtYUrEQS@FW9qbRbdKnRtiHICQqk6d44oROm3pbk0iPtsuhY9Q46dPEDK1GtPCrc3TAF4Yy3HwN4wN5aaUUCtVcFQxPfae28KuVhpXC7@A5lWAIP6zseR0rIye1reCeorbnt86PeqY2R/hVXtXQvYCjMSgVg9TOfupEt@WuUrlJniZv6dwxHhrFM/Bqh8nVGrjkTpTSZnLsmorRrNWqzepAGZjOGAYxpEfX/LjQhbI1xiHx@Im3Ax/6WiidWNHR4gt1vUuj8ChU6@DR9rXq2s2wXAbY24pSpa9xCmGh0n2qV4eUwQPFwsMiO/vQnSt4KqPd/3C@iXDrQMib22TNYlA6LxM7NieOv/@f8nOD@XEDmlXxttKrnqH/Z7ytJgWhkUyefW6Adl0VK@OwXLWHLf75JLEF6n@hMgI/aSVX0YA0/ITOEu3Tkyt91qq2vh1VrKo5tJQKgX/WoF9spprQHs8ymUwiI5YSGQl6P@gVIRh@K/Ceg58EPwiXVhqLi1EtKjAmJMSRmJISkiIlHGNTB6KK5TLSFiqFXuEpx@KZZS3aMZi8mqQ6gsZYwQyAQOgzU030oxDrUJE1Dh6Lf3xaSLJcnsUqH4EE1lK0k1qLPc1VOtE11oyBB3Th8MuwQq4SrNJorNKtsui3sUp0MVa1lY98nEFFNBeBmHzEsWQPB2fiYkFK3CSbyVtNtp0laSVTPhsunSUlKJ34ubcqvK8JDSD1bQgGJ8F5e9AOKuDnNVSuT0w0gomfWQEdUFOgYqRSpuKChExXagD9oviRSL5vLRqJrGQikVikAlCL4E3SJ3ZDIiICEizyRAK5BX11WShlIHwibO7kgI@qClIofBvqqLbJcqVQ@CZ0e3O7Wpsony/ZeCzHk97rE8Z6cRhhp2mpMdUMs0VyJVM1nF6oV@u9w3rFBa6v00g4PdkewM750chkevFr1zbjq7Vv@fMcl7whRVBEW4Z2Nmq4C7CZbChs34Q4/WjnQHo1XkufhwQB25@7UhUt5mN8gP5dmCzusvUb72O65VdITrnMm9VZI/bdnqrdFLPJGo3agG9ub8NxKDzuiamliZjtfdqKEgrrhuvENQ0HBBjI7HxewHG8wsyj0rcr3xa/fXWyf7K/xZ6J5WK5yIly/iyRkCJSZJU9A7VRPdwMhc3PRl76Tn9RCZfNSDYXyU6NB86r4VE145eHPkoZPcO1Pfg1zmCI3oiBq1qVnkorZdV2l96iZXtoKlbsqVTIlH/47T/KjKrVzNOMKJUzmXwsbP/w/b/Bg82ZlbDrkgor4UbYXd7LrcTghZaRMlK4lvb8pRUJ4ibdV2klH7ZLn8MZsRgKF199@MzYKgwuap1eT82QK@1xw9INv9jNnCt9x@d29Rb@a7dnq6u3NMNx6zrwdnvLg6f@6TG57oGZhDe@bX7bLH@XXOX/q3BbXN93iykU8gKLhT@A4LHtcChcisB4LMIyeTwqGQdJC13VGfM5UarcVhqm@a1pmjCgWNbpT7GX8W/yvmzbq/DuvSoYyPI1icEAJJ0@j70GQVsqlQpSJhz69d0rvbwQYssLdRbhdvN4N41Gcf2Td5GpD1viFNXyQnLjaH/95eYx9tOKjh98Z@v7eykMwm@ST45OtjVFtrSx@1HyMUJh9368fsAMi51sHFCcUzo0S740E@WmsrTTKbufD0tcMSmVxcXZfFrMpaU8k4plcaWcKTAZ5J6NRjJc1xJGZVSsdcMc8wFjdD1GkRfqCINhuyqM6m2lzJ4f7FIMki3LCxubr/bZ/t7uu5Tny/2Pt3eO2NH@1vFp/XATyvFq84gJ9SO2cySw053j7f2TY1bfe8cg@LC@d7yzeYQI0iGUmajIcoL5oze2ao/tNGq5Ng3hprxto32pONP@smXKabTyPO2t43efFPxoyrT/UFdhfBgcHR7VF7huyBC93OlYITytq7bZAo4HF5ZBy8DDwn3RXmH54dtPopVfZO3cXmSFtcU9Pbu6wjTR/WNabpA9ZIuLi@e64Hc4wWL4g9OgF57zAL9Jnnbeby5ECzm2DAPRTC42CdnbP1gQvbeF08PjBckPO9xYyPgvO1sLWf9lE95y/tvW6cZC3n9bq79cKEyi7a0vrPhvG5vrC0X/DZh0oTTBubexIIkhj1hXoAgu0KdTo1s7u5tsGYBilalQnB9Ex4w3ECIKyhs3nYIkZ8vL130jQWOc1ngGuqN8CdoDn4JaQPXxDOnaSLBlw4QbKKYADNFC/jhDtnrthIsVTaZBNxW6CS1ggRawQABPH6BHOLZYZRn@bfgu3ycS5SY0E0w4selo7jc2W8UhQA2YIUE22OiINsRQ3G8o45fkOcpol@ZQu7TvnEAlyKlgCbEYnuvcO9nd5YmZpPVGBYLkH6QX5uA0TMAGRYQ7Fh18eeXwaqG6QFotuFoMfuc5dDtVm6HZ2kRSQDkXFtqAYJq6V7KWYKjFJXBvAuLFF35eBIAhGNwiuPiB1mi0jWXtKU6bMhRDYm7ub/ES4u6GKpuu5RjDRIlSFMxPonz@zLy3c2f61Zp@1SMct4ucZ4vj4zmtImwM/Ra8k8QEQVYTKOYCckw8DrGhOBQWKNcCEB1@3MiCl8saJCRG2JMnlI9VeCtFKAmMF6cUWRJBEIFLMCIfIvOztkjZjS2kl3GDEW03IjO/2I9wo8utsW8gBiTrbEZnatVvhX51LugwOq7MCGQ3qNvBugZ3NtOEdxSPwMkJ1oJmkmBeoFTAQBwxJpiSYF3wnpGpTVUHzlWsiUz0WAEaI9X@3gavIW4Nify5B5UY5F6ZKgyExRNsvsToCwstS5EvKx4UyEOCAr5FpokiITjcw/EONyjaMm8vyJYY@zExd7bKHh/x2MAOLqcRWdGABecVt7jkWZsA3cHvIsP2WwX0nCU5snjchfC5zAXbnIZLJjncrceXXyjE5mwpFr@6FCiW7y3F5iOL8Q8rBXRrExaBUoCIjwLeOEDTbbo2M/NQQF9IKKg0Pw4FdKATXoI2PoXgEfGhy53ET359fOiky7NNGdot1CCXCjzK9Gt7@rUz/YrNF3xktrrKMjn2mbXQJRXAhYYMWBEcHS4rpyN2p19pQqnKFC9O15fAPAXgORSVHAwZ8K4wRgmSsvFbMfIAv1hWZfWt5s7e5vF0KOJL2U03433H0DVKIzYN5mYIw@0ovsT8HEW7SASub0YPeBoJomfz6Phws/4qAfmLsdVJC5jVAeDmtoSpEtx6KYCvrrShP@4kWPSozpZj7AnmLMHcyQl8eXQSmmErgOreFDtDM0NJiRzEf59uSWFskaE5SQlRFo2xz@fn0KWKK0wamJ@zg6y@ku2wcXYFlV2Ox9dBXCnvCZg93jS5soGQHW4utDw3sQtRZDkryxylDxr3SLTu4qdy3WLfRt2id9zaNGhQZlcYnm5H2eIap4F@cVq1eViLpL4R@QB9sRmDH3bnNAkZJ/0c2ZNCPQWL56WjfG1evqTRTuclyfOySonezcOv3YlbGC6FZo7Uk40fw3RMGU@du4H7NN17gF5WKMQnbQKm3qIGfiXKiZXJRA/KlGYT7QQ3m1Fb0brArMbQakOXj@qy7YLhhaEpHkgNCR3TgS55UH@aDuAfoEcrrNDrzCBEIyzgjYYlo5RiKOTnzHYUk3IVyAbOy@E314MJwgB76h2qFU9vBnIcK7ta8ZaM7cFDdjZlnYvjGNr9xBxvEM93fX02nRPms82cMDTCOC@KZ1VgTtjFcDAvByAY7glxzwXPCdGN/XkRuHGrSUDjLEDAsyCBG41obH7VQ7uarvGAdTKi/7E1VFxTWzv7ARYE5dLlwEBdhzcUYNq2ip/hmEXkWyaAmNFRLGAkwWer2ISTZLutqrPoPUwuIjrlSx@dYKNyuw9Yv5EyxVgigDCAscOtEt@HkwWQQg7nIAmzI@J9bzrV9lEjC87incRPoY0PvQPDu0kEw3wAHkMnsFj5HvACmmfzQ3xmntPkJujKdxmH/HGSH6tfmjJkdx@0VwgpFiToPzT55Ncmnwykj23yRyVdZWfT@WjEA@9l8JiU0WvgPyohL9fTqcW@qsRBrlGUy3vYFw0OBZLhhkamk/XRuBLI5ymvKIQePR4pJBBXENFXyBeqPtcMwrzYk/5nucqSkh@HS7xJa6D56EDmQ2gipdlE28LNJhmVbDZxZqnZFHgK1PFihxfsdN3GxsNSoKU2DQqNCklZSAjJZP1ofWcnqepCgn/koCrYjmEpTbQNJyRwYbsqkMBqIkxf0cyq4G5LlG1GsYX706gH0oACfjkRAuKp7OiUyMRo8JeTaweLZDyiSMZMYhNDpo9I7ZBSQ5sND6VkcYuAXkLrZLQOrQBaioqChn@@AfnB6JJ1lymjIjil72aBp2vTTJ@Nplx4lujRRD@3rtEmyq5Ko2qa7RM8I0fCHZtEbmvHqR5EMOFUzn3CAX3DjZHBu47i6lk0PZQSJsZO3Yyl3JIG@N1T0LiNmEmHNm34yM1vwpubtHEacyarE8FimFj4MwHtIkEFHBgm3H3bSOD2rSOBG@0joZcn6sCNxpEwRtd1uHaSwEWWkuAJ7C1MDLMO5JE6GOLETdD6hqvJTbKFXT6WhHp9CpyWfpyiCJHS0MJ11MUbiwtlAYpuk1WmWctMCD/POFOsEborZMmUOGYzoDrMQzrX3FMs8RuopIAihqLZdnMDcRMCE7gSQnGlcgMGnwHe8UQMqs8zfgaf9UREUJKEH3/SXwWMO1WnhhdIERg88MxMIvBZpuBnU0m5j5V9FWRSY0EorrjNyTfuKL4340EMnqIWCz0wkvr/zTgpWCX/hQ6V/r8fFN0Z@vwjD2UeGMJ89WjlNzgs@K8K/X9V6H@EQv8b0@bvUclnUd5t8TPq@hfV8K9Xv0jmjaHbsHpXOPWW@TF62G9IEVj5Kj3Ay/WZ9JAu8OX@2UOTCXbrP7KXDv06fdwpnG4Z9Xr9eCBZh8/rvXq/foh2tNbE3fjpRW5t43rt@VqnvrHRe9Fb31NeF@u5XfPl2@K7591PHxXQ3rf3X7z/pJntfujtoXl9qhxcZ5WiXR8OP@5sj53ttZPB@lH@3cq1uKnlu2vKxw3N3nh1/Pbl8fP8Ufz644uDF58G4sA@6IpyaZDdflV4sz4@1UP5K/Wks7Wr7g@OOpsnmcHuhvpuK74u7h6VXkvi7ub1@@z6dTwvpnfMl/vPD08uWpvvtcOd3Xed9Y@GXPh4eW3upDul7vrF4ZvQfva1tP1xf7@3mSk9305fb3TNjpjZ1qz8xdvDg7WTd9v9l/LmYCt/Unp7MT4o9F@/vnL24r3caWH4ys7F9frr15mX@vOrq83DUEs2jq2scmq8lszr6wOjNFhRXu5t9wavLUlP7@ffxI8Gx9cbm2vax5VR9uTd6evr3NG74avXL97vi@rRUWtTLpitTubo4jgXag@yO/Grk82Tovy8c/p6cLWznX@3kX7VV/bqnQPt8nlv@71xdLC7U8/aQ13aXb/S3j3vX7y63Fjf0YyDS02v59J57bjzbn8/dPJCbW0o22/tF/WL/rt0fu0y9y7eMZ8fX3zqX75YOzrZL2ZGB2PRWLcPW9vd0cZhIVNMt7WPh5@6xivp5HW8cHXxIqO@q39yQtlP43xpV3unDPQX8Xbv/eijlo6fSNL6@51P794dbV9Zrbp@8vHN1uGF9aqj79v74uGLl69a2mXRuTDf60dHUlt8rly@iotyaHSybUMdKcdyfuV4sPvaHG0YHw933tuFT/Gr08ussnF5@Kb@8VBsXevmW93aVQfrYmdfrr8xnM3h6Hm7dHVyua3tfty334VebUr5/JbRtde6b3Klt@nn8e7l87dr0tFI3NMPu7mCtffm9amqbvbfnnw6bOe33pjFgaP3Xn86GWzGN3dH/U9KUWxpR@8u9dBJ/ujwIHOtv1QHztb24auCsy/uvjnobI@l@mtFutZX1sf5jZFVyJ5uvLXeXW7rZvqd@nF4ICpX8c4708m9Vlvd9hu1PXgZOnrRP9k7eHO9ky9Yzwe6unZQFPd2t9f3ep3cy/HOq@Hmbuui83znrfLWPC5cZjbXTgsbb4@yzvHlS6fUvhpkD4rxY23g9E7ioRfD/nDl4NT6@Gb0PlcftJTsofbOGK9Ig/UXZmb0pr65/6l3eWAae9JWZpw@2TUuNfHT8fWnbbtQH8eLoxNnYDjH0igvvQ5lrz@Zzgvzxeuj/bUX@@9fyDlVPZUvjt50xOxJMa32rexOofBc2tzqDj4OSor0aeNVVs4O@nF79zLdWe@cvDm91C4GLwcX7VCxZLfXdt4PZWOzlZHEd2vdzbyyu7Z7LCknvZdHuY098eBt5@Dk4@i4s/52ePJmXxU3L16Udnu5t4dvSi9X3h/bx/Kp8faltRcaFbOGLRVK@evsUam437eOsqcXJef9y4vCmnbakl7sZAbKlmq9LY6Ll@an/nXv@kgRW73nGx/lw@4mSNKTA1HODy/3Rkeh7JvjwdWKuRZ/d9l@@VaXtOKpupI@/nhRuuz3X15vtHOn9U8f5fzzC6V0tJVuaVv55/HD9dcHF72N00/FXEdc230jvx1t9p13odfb6sZF6fRyfzSWXm8djQd1UdfyV0en@atjY@3odPuo2H/Vsrqt7Ys@yIbB@OTieni1raz0R9fFl/2LN7K4@7a4rtu5AzH0QtkZdA6PX76tx7sZpeRc7b/bM0@Lp6P8q6JxWjL2i@rLevf56PV@d1NcMdXT49HJZj@9tq4OiiBTDrQTa33/9fb70xemGMrohbVP60Z@5WP8avSucJo@iO8O37WPM4NTy9p@q1pbb68O3r48qu/Ed1rj5weX8v67zfzR3vq6/SK@pRaU8Xb22q6vZ7WuEbIHa6O9kWWWsu8vd3vQExidUuf5cfZUt@v17vVO8WizXn9ut3ZeyKPR8@4K9BF4bZ6@MaqhX3MbiSFuHpE/ZG5kJTSwey1jBPKSn3AM0fm0EJ1PC/ETabQlm@9l/nV6OXQcPIiBx/Bcw/XDFihrrGOg8pBiO74hY/yOSYINDIiuoqttmPREtO6Rkw4O@DS403wVnqGkD5kqI1MzVPxEFH6uAsek1uSbg6nQvs4GYxxvOsqAHw9R8StPrt1h@sIF/5gW2T0NLbTbzPvca4qs6voff/0ACoSp95JkRrnHksl2V5N7Nji0Drk@hI58M/@YgqbKOPmBSUi7TVkS8@7WVPpEI2buGD9Otfec4ffvcBusN@KQQZkYk@0ZnKQi@zMKfhLSVq8UbUwfRFE6qRDf8fmoXZBBP9wrPu1Htl9n9oaCuqFYMxtATR7RW2lNLz9D@z/PltPuEisqQ03ZaqkOfnC8yU9pNHmK3p43c3rvIR1wdhdouWKEmg1ZTebOgTzCt5lYSDHasz45ZIj76SBFUFG93YbLyyahpH1XjL8EMC@b9@NWB73fFOop3B1VmcJrAK2GQCtakL6zZv@NTZscfaBKiC/Wb77dOW66X83hWwynTnbds@MyQOWK92ZWeAkC@XdzfndbJu4wgOzjtCM3Og5FvTI4Lwu07xG3R0Jt4wh7stsyBVxDOw0Qm0m7Uc5yDb6DUKStex7B/ThPOCc8CeTqyYSgC@6GCp8HHhmPb9DkIHfLi4i7lqIQAO3m9I6izGz2@w3z3j0109Jk/RJdFb5VFsYLVjtQWfQ9kEA5cCrLL4u7f5Kf6YNyQ1R/G@wko4LlVwsBuBtivWo@0bE50357jMNr2E8a58cwDX/UpWlGOzoJXva23PCyxbyUOPxMUvs4k9jFnbWGNeYJ4fRMtFIBENynQzJB0b3dqoFSVyfUQHS0qSeQC@DbiueF1hSUST4T7OHc8qQWiR1oB9D8rPLNQAh15merwZO6XxYCvWPBwkxFnRDH20IEzvQycwwTiNB1OQ66MeIRvjv1DlX4Ti@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@s7OwTu0gQfL3OCSQlWhGEISBSQGEWIDCKEaKD2mu2B6cNBV1yM8R3fvAOjRPZwxRnPD0A9odrvpURijJMPV7gBn/uRN@pDOH2jEKG5u7OGjzebh7hjdmfvOVThApYjwSZ3r5iLHKNfxHVZ5x@eUR0VsgCyjQ9o3LLyqppOHz299F1sHnIXfhY7j0ilQwjGI7vaIfGF6jRVw8XGSenxkeIQHek7aD5AMVaBcQa7VpisITnG/PvNRf65NDr0RrGJVODwI7oZRAohzY4P63tHW/uHr4hyB8367sF2HTHDALMtWx1GH/TBBqLrisY7VZ@eIex@QULzMskt7@szKtrbIFj@ZUhOPABsUkiTfGdzhOXlTH8HnnvPi0ASxYcGpaLZUcw5uHHvqg/mFsaeg5DXIs@12xW6eZrXE1KHd7cn9ORoDSUd0dJQbD3iAGPTB45kncuTtIdvDUaZ9HVIarmoR/WIXyz@Obxshr6RjXxkD01cHVY6QpD8crut2GSwYUJ9QKloXUrElSwBQoHP/NJP5Ac/m@L3vS4O@kQodbqir/dO1NxpZRG0R067H6XjBhQkjsXTkW48tZLUIjdl/snuKdVRnVYZ70uMp3bBU7uA1LjAZRezCpnaOLuYUsTmkUf1yHPBdWNPM@Pqib@VnGquC43e7qNhJZoL4VKHKgyriayIGOMpWffEq7InXiuetMT5yt3DSplL2GmNzO1wJv2nO2DudIBs0TtzG3RyhUZfQwvrn7/oyjW@UE/JDzp5QwyCJ05pgjrtwXniE89Q3csZiAmkIZ2WOXOTa1Cn4uOLughZ0stPLKBr0ClMd1ZA1UFaTA6nuWUlVdKw3YFiwBPFqtsLWx2vkRPkpDOzOrMHuhAIffmBw8mpBH6MjydURCd9XrRKqJFDJjorBXBdNZmECDE@r0E6DYhbLANlT3XmF6N4txhu4TydTOUnYFDUuW6JiwIE/QzjHvD1Eq/MLXegHN5hOIwcCxRMrLgnKLwTvScHLCtls4Hjv/une6xQmJwORqNtLJcRJ0eO0XwbK5RCP2qebDKfwPkRG45bochWyDM4dAddUNE0aMT80VGx68e88WHxiD/GFV@5WuYjWNsVx27XYLPB0MYpSibjCB2PVkojKRVaAKFIc8Dul0@9zhsAe0PZknVH4WcsUZC7K7uYIEVEHVaxoFwtaBm4bQwl/gCN59lDS@ETwODTMdq0SRJxUDyo6eGAdiMlUGG4Uiw0A6A67kH/BZI5Ljtw0VDjTOB5esKh5vEGJ6ErEqhF4yQLJyN1y0g9PvXiujKkrhzvipTL412JujTvI8qYASKvyypEY@4OLbgEvtPN0Hh82f2SnNckfeCJ6J83NXi3k@GDU28c7qLhfczdkb/amDMZQ9zVDvZBI3cTE6GiMjVi3hk4kgDeEai2Nw/BgegxalD3RLj4aBQpCOOXjsrnwhnJCNIiqJeiLsVCrsNdOq69Pgpe8D8jT/xchdYXc3cGjN0Dc/7xSBcCWT7GIdyzkbMQ2D45xCiIA3LBG@pyerL/YIQ4/PNuKL6JQ7xROLpj7rgAEfBxLaldPP/8TNr8UrhtlBLlR9Jmc0pBsUBbng/Gi@yCYekCYJApkkfLvhEcDnZyMDn35gFS7mlC6qHMT6X22My7yd0BmqLEI7PuE@LWnaubhxQiD4wrhS9SudtqXDUzUD9cSYJKdBmBeJbavTtV4dLAkwo8d61ADK4ze3E8SUIh7qHfuyLHhfIdyxnvOLAn0P1pzsm53nkF5ZzsFdUrJtUgfcpdU03qGqfL6jaLYFmT0t3CrgQK650yniqsG8kr5137Djo4uppxze0vYIciuCeXhW86CfZNBxdDXJ9gH@VRY578mz7rHGiQ31YnLdIvn59XOjTrv/C26q4domgP8jvGQ7yi18jxW97UBUgIbugVb3M9j7Ww4KozoPRMxcvE3Glnn509FN0uyGvaqo9menczHqYJxxCWKvuO46Eu6JNiTQF7YJ9JzmMGYj5sV4WSBmADXORK5qlG6nEHBsTjbn9WnZoNnhygvpcRg1hc2Rk4ovxgfJIpd3MxxjDeTc7H4UVxu/tJ@68EMzK@NyNIDlojcvs6f82Im0S4/YeujE50N9PV3EDvMjNw@@gqYq7@lhc9PSBqTvQFf3TAxwNB3cBVtD1lECe2QIGHsTE/Gp1gkPq98BMLIx/5Ah8ezYOYZAEkGI1MTQQFEs9hJjAsMgODmLvZpNohipq8TqbzTRVJEyE@dl6MJ@YZIktnkrgMyJ1x6U6pptAxOuRMs3EVbvyDVFk0s07j1KD1D6z4ZSw8LllOxlkmHg72djsQCnVgago/uSPtNuv7O75pK9Z3HLOcTiu2gV52yrB66Wv1Uk1zwNCRa7YqqQyxnaORKh7S3DyBrgwNTjkpdqTwzQqo96Ja9oGGk8ow9gEjoQUsHYC7XdB49baCH69xrnH/gIvATgUzC8GyDXq4obOxYbQmuZfdkzk8AwnKuw2Z7wFhhq0UZCDdlh1bGStpjJhuaXAbyGgsOw1D8jSWML2vK7sQ@wiahJK6kK/k0EYgY3RyeiZVsmkXSuLcEYU4@O132j2CcwgO7otkLQPqxt@f6g4SyOCloWtjpqMJgB5gukJokCqQFHLeNRSTdty6izq05UGhcUROLBVI2NtuD0fxsP9OpSAsHwvx7xaX8XyHbSC7WArtTaXoU3taZvZk8IY5vYmCj/On/dponOvL@zT8LR7pdCCuoT9m38e8PR5k/wvIft/Oj3Qap0dNTR4z4VomM@VsPbciFso41lJ7OrEhthY0ohPQ2JURGum2cWMA9uNeXE25UjSWxWp8o9pDADxyhlCkUNi05N5A9gCj2TLDZAI2umh8PXWifxJkGNq0TxfPTbDJiBpPpjEmTbDRCS63V0Fiut5uv6DEQGrB7SlueTYMk5XB0VFawx51Bnguy4uBp6PkRAsjyLFatBV7Cs8yPCHrZPka2jE2/qpvvwr3ExkqO4Nm3mDeAoVQCVEpoOlXee4rXnzsORAssKIDHTZf1YAeYZk13cEonyUAaOzDohzO5vOetHjugXSMnX2ctaEE@eZiLwSLaLqWI@/dU7LMAntKQCSgvSlkTDKBlU57MyOROn7H2XtZi/BQmjWKcvdkioj3ess@Obz9C12@@2SVbIIxMhpK5IxVvF31UoXdeoC4BwQ1HNxZkox4OwdQw7RwbWayIwVIL3ijsIfQBjKQ/QIkVRyyGfZLgWLwDd4NPtvlqiCzwVLDW8MC/6pY8ajBP/vu1/9kMesJr80FKvgifUT@hrnqtNDmCzG0SuIuME3lFTsvl0eIOzgut4uPcn4gj2lucGcTadI04U@o8ozyOVcQFqhzJqlLSbAR6@HsOx8@JdjYfUWb@yFuWFtMjKtSxbe@rejDwQ0ORhI8ytBMIPAtU0DaV0J4d0d0Fk/cb93QS5BYR0EeIkGBXmeeP05t3IgJJt1WKOU2fcqNi3jQI@7y/ty9WOc64iufwVCE/hu8myh/0xESPD1cMiCH5DkyjcQkNU5EP9ejsXEZHSXGIDoYnkequaMOdLuT8/Q6DgSRjRJ3ncYVMDgP25Rx3bGJtIt6FshYc1SFAdL/2963NTeSXOk9N35FNXpmgCLuILubJFjsGzmaXvfNbLZGCjYHwqVA1jQIQKhCE5huKry@O@xwxHplrVfeS/iitcN@tR273gj7we/Sf9hfsP9APt85mVlZhQLJnhlJYce0QkNU5smTt5OZ52SeS3vh4Q5P/H@B4ZVlwQ5kAL/tEGClAkCSUB3N7HI@DzNtffNSCfkk1CXzZ5NtSNm6/FI@Zo/xS3kb/0XsJI/HoT0vtxeu1kuhEu3FGg@BUU@5WOouN@8b9Hepvan@Lo2H6e@K8TD9XR7Pr9Vfc2P8A@4IHTH8BzIORPZ7JFETtEmUe4p7DhLr8Qm198N06dkEcZVSpTkWxnLp8WQyDuGCPbsFUmdGIzjfSqc670kd2/SbBOSaXB81Nuu09BDVIMzJEp@OwS8W@Tdib8r5RfzkUO621RnNCcC8xTf65rOS@qYKXHWU2El6SzT9Q1Wypwo7QWzbG9Yv9hyrqpZpOHdUZDCHC5veu458WjisrrP6IrVGF8FAuU5WkRn4DpRLF0FadhE16mp/TJbCqDuZpfQkorTSrtScEG87@cciJcVcd956a2rz7kzkavETRo41973zkiZwmQy@6S2U9ClNotjjAd@2PRJFbOeFup2C2ROx8NHpdDw7OXXgKAo8IGBFpXwwBncP7pK4egRcncFXzbZWiyvG3Tf3xzXn1cQhIZ/t57Fyn75wHoHx7y5wlyx3AUXrmFAaVjduaN7pRnylfYN3egN8LBd9cuMQV89zZjVgD/RATXiKmziq/oDJKaNifYhVGoYDyXeiCP7/wVkH0gV0Py42wTNMXBAcgPbxxczKDQOa3VghY6u13Dq7uU@IVLJaW89sJJuhphvZ9XHVV7@kcXKLmL67oeagdrRmz/8NzJ@pVV6vSe6/gjSpUk2VZYbzSciFcjQxOzDNO4Mzc3jWEEolCZxQPhtPIRsuypmYz3Efx6urc06yF4vKgCtVVXNOSZ59C0WjzNL84nbaoali0wEgohYwayVvZ3gvQww7lH7K4qgpLAJwyKwc/M5KM8Y9vDLrwssjMR33fL8fgmXtgFa4nUWYN6jlql8J@0HnBBIiSep669XN4ftolhZPg55YZTx6gaZM/R/PgqkI22hNleaS9X6IFB6d@r03DIswTTH2SjCq0LCNosp44IQ/nnWmuHIYT51SIcypPV5OmgOliZPmo9QG1UoAM@V5y0yIBQz2E64gU2Sl7@twVaP3PFbWQdSQQqhidqg7I4ytffeDW5OqQ/uVuZCh43moLHSDkPFY4nfZGcyG2IvHkyrysBMmO2t/gbHs3vTEiWGim9ZHAkg21mSuhVGpoUwNhiIf4@oklp3mavCtJWhUtQK4ItBGxrLG1wwaDWVi3BLPO2wUFN9fUDbfnxdBb6GGGUDXYuorEQJl6m6ZK1lGy0fxMtbReFSxMQvYMmKCA5h73fnzfkvz54ABGmHvoQ0G5u@4Yex1cFnJTVfSJ6107iUIWXWF9oGz2TDqjPzxLBwuftOEkLvBoUkV70xJC/78ofpMsuMQw0Q6qyEYgPO49pzV3aCbAEGdNu/mk23k5A/VVoOJOxurc9YZKjOYsKxjC@GZqHiIvCcqD4ej1glI5cBlAm56oCYQsY1XWdQGaOtkc7FRVOVyWsGu04tmvImejqFcAZ3SGe6DoOMxhYkYTwk2bPQFyMcTfyqVEbUtxjNHn89Er7GrT9ogY1@bAVWqjj7Gj70Z3QLdy0FCeIDbQgWVwxPfKkPbLzWcwPnuiNqtj7eur@4ocLjJ6xYCj6IGrpb@AncgNnBxhV@7NnmFw50vqgTuVLk63ArQYrNuyUTPvnhTyfeuFvRT@k/MMuu7Lg0rBKV0@/GSwFoVy9dyWoANWqxoUQw8aGrswMKC1iWBHgXHNz28tYjWBt@dYRbPiUD8zrR3Sl2i@QpAMNGUx6kf9HnYSIbDtbdxZR46hB7Rk1xhoEezsy5c0gx4vIyZJr974JKcQIoxapdrjk0vA97hghLR82uoevL9cd81a0uqYrkEwg8BmnsknKCqTXx/qQYG37FmkxmdQVF94iqkiWHB95FKhJsS5Y9@Kat5rD3XG5Gv2UpjbFyC0Y0vz1ImYbjwiiwVp/Px9I28HOHajXf@qBPwvTfeAkVhGYX0jR4e@cM4T14y9OVcHNaE1zMOltNOdPUlr6amiDbFoRj0iOFUPMDyhteKlZaNNnJdaIu2sJ7cQNVUFjSjpKy8XMrGbohHv7nKHaLYBtVt0y011p69FGSu1VWm2LVNhwPFXSVoQ0EqigC0bjmu39WVpK6jwmgYShovMg43vuRpsJYyd6rYKRcQ/6WdevgUrfij3bpejUIfnifUEddhlIR7lqrumjZvEH2yxPBzkGDPBHD4euPGO4Zcp7acudLvYkuruWh43UjJ3470@Ags6Y0biw8ZHR4LoyYe38nnmZrVMmC5wygDNoU2UlKe3hgHsvQzTFWUkqeEO6Dj3UEwBWW@QZ/2ZXgYuea5Xi3QMKqGEdOOddJXZPch@s5ad51hOFauzPhglUIhvxd@2EuMXoFSvVp33dkATcFLP5WJDVSWrVNuDsyWw6q58uAvI8XgrHc4Aw5Z/66lLagd6ovVCkGxyYp64VcFj/SdONArNeqBuiOTHjhrbVWt6oN2YYRO8IO35c6GparvTf0T@nMQoEX9sAB@ybx8V3N7cpn44vnjZ4f7B@2D/e/vH7zc55KsyG8MimeTGt@Uhedw7j1SeAthwiFO7vNpQOc4ThyOswQJ/GVvHEXOpyTu@iSOv@lQyc7Mz618c28@WZ33KvSn21L@UJh5Nr5nTeMwgInQDKpK1L9zEcDlebgYukL8dAayQypovQ7hyUDiQuWwZ9JmLjnYP7GSumOOiMgQyrIBR8p4EJ2DA1TSRPKNmU6aYZ9Ws19VOrYaGlcOsb8E4xABDADlQ@t2UeWA7PZapYH3iecEG4m2ShRlkr0f1Z0XUu0eV@vsSb/AQ3aG49FJTnlPsFrAnBsdWmWEe9/WQ8xGQVQF9BbgKRAjLT2SDtUgH9Qa1Xrt23NpED9i/468FXwNk/yvaee9bKefGT8py2xfxwCweJyLlA1dImxSpgVddrSmpEFdqqKmqujrmZOvtiZX6Nd/xxbkKwzIVes2fjtG49@uPfe1zay/sY@F374ZTiYBJ6xyNPlmqphefHsGO/@vWI18mLnIVVYU35lOZJtOqIBqH2I8UVgrsPYxOI/Hz@XCHldN5von1NrdKpxRiifTu1ZC0dZEsEkqzcfxaJQm8vWU6BMa9Am18t@YOvzqvmbYAsTdzVY7/oBeW8YRiY7WP0gT3gTquULF3dbWv0i0X9drq@1DpX26AO8ZX6RhzanmJlWkebd5/95JqIGLpYvo@DL5Kw1zY96incpbl3FaGV2dHfrOTEqm1N/lUjCjtAnyFqkYWRJeKxliTlGrbZOo4OqthEK8kqNcjetiefxSauvxCMaXpexEzL7EV20trmFsEIiKzwbYHrjpOUqgjC9jV6FMTo2ei1WVqYW2ZBNiXuD/f7G2MiQoBh7fGVn9Do2svrMa@c5q5DurkcusRm7drM3Caa0bjGrEmg2dyjlx/7lbtKD2njuff/bg0Dn8bN/59NWjv@P88Pkr5/MHzyjlufPi1cMnjx859P/9Zy/3HS5g/n3fn0Ll3qGp3/N7Pt/ON@v1DYcxLwUo33Beds6cz8Y9/y0Rz07YObt/Kh/VkR/tSqn9t/50MZbnoAmUWSJlNcF3RfLWpG@cYHHdJUo@wzui9uWJNrI3z1Bultj2gsOhGwNuedtjHoT1uPhZyRhtEPyYUglNR55kWXcaT@vMtPSrjho48@@DR5CYwqcvnQfP9hDpc@/x4ePnz146nz4/oM8XP4SbHWfvMdzGPHyFLAZ8@nzv8aePHz3gBGlAvergbo0N1i9rQhXgPCq9N4MZwoMNIRWqr4RX71u53GisrSJCpzAbxe57@kRSeHcXZ6ctdtFe/OjBwfe@D67G/7GTzyPIpeVQXVkgfFSH0QjVpqJot8SZOljLSkM2pLOF8xGyWzm@A@LfZUcjd/mdOPCd/CNcI@JBmuNmC8OmUVNFNwk3UGlHsJ7DERgKhfIOo9yl2vj2QNeGi9WB/kDR@8oxK@TIW9pLa8hIEZzx8agnYXR1AtG9aHVztdFUAHAhpBIEAHcwSIg6b/zHuCRxbiuIWQTBnxLuSMKXZ5NPz8E1wsBVJTyUQCCbqk0ybzylCHDUCUYyjwmzJtkdOEYKFwkZHk5yhkN95coqccT/qzc2vMoSZJ52wQGtbC1UxM9uRA20t592BlHoFD0Xt8EkgvijQDS1ToYdEvf4XngKg6W3UCPgajc9/NvVjuo1w8mBOLUI0104yXaYcnvq4PevW45KPlyqEXp73GkoTKn4T1c24OFSA74OGkJUsfcLuBWaRMzYMprxQJFyMRwTRZLI5/wkGdVo3J/1/EQBJesUvwy@@spVg1yOi1gqPtw6o2GHUA94CDmHDyp2c0FCDGtKnuI1SuawmOxB/DZ8BmWIKRr4Iz24qjZbeNA1Kk0cVSn4@RW1djtsDHdlrUzxohtstq@J8RnFz9@hmOXxM0kXYrKR5kL4c4YSAzw7TeHmZeBAsWgRcUskuEMu3jt@4oS1oy82vd29h68rP/lR@bhWO5FtodOXxwtRSpRnFhbJaXkY3UnWBtQrTSHNhbMuSmt9Rtktsco1MmJcTgNivu@3WyZPrlWX00ccLyuZzonv33tSqsL2JkxCiCQT725l50hXWeYyx46rEMR7JzUWnnV1Splxmv36PuLaYxZaNCIj7COsXmOHVWP9GsvbNR70aGfJKT5Nptvgd3UsckVR/K9oz0fti@JDr7Tr1jQULyYznEW9RZc15oarenWB6eXzagnd3uXoaP@@PrrNS1snx8MHYdu7FNsHta1SWo1LjiUL1/XR/uQStHK4fS201PfyasRySC5jM5RuiLP80S1N81fU@KOlueO1R2hw9iKiqkFq1TYbDeEhriiX4tQ0LuDaaGKG6OXh3v7BgZPfxy3bNpWlfa8z6rF9KbZB4L6pPR2JHTJvdlXDNJkwQYZ50ikXYl6arPayxZw5eCu2CsWDlNV4mM3CRO0lyWSurCPkZGEWAobXsiHqkUu27p3eg8IjhfjiCJpQTjxpVgdzmd28JYePONnnTSYet7LwxuGbYGKYGX@unHXxVfV0YSPSjDCOg84JXr6z5@9z4Y@3dT3CYPk/nnGHoYTfg7985yVVPMFLcTU5g5dMi55S1llhKr2lx47N8pIc9jcnKBOL/ULxwta2rphj1TThjz@yItkxf3of7/wLldk7U/edeovnlB17Qt340CsmjyBiMkkMdu7bVEHFjy/UEcajYc5JzzDk9lr7iFtzpFvJ0cwU7tZqoI@Jg799J709pKui3fbSqirfTlVySiRqsuJuLdegMwnzndu316/Cne6FLl75prjlDEnvn9HZ5G3HQhkuQlYVIsp9/Kys82MCuGToPJIC@0W9YFIFidXJOFMSfefDyG4fteV8Cls8aszzV4dl3Bela3Wdeapt2djlRLKxM8hSH6wlbDoqq2Zp9C8ur@4hB3W7or6bH16fLDYA4T784tcSJvNgPMFWSYz4tC1eUUkk3w6hFRehhAQfNJ5@rRiY93UcyyOJN3dfXrhhIy013o/Gb6DXryNnqthmeTxDVc86k3fvccH1nq9MJQ82AapsUHbufyk6KhJZ835/zEoEAxPK8r60MplG2/zbth18cxvqg5wnANYDpmcGsPBJwSG5Zxu3CjrUZKEkacSfmKSKJBGtRpA9TPqapMMuIZgMFya9Jul9H4HnTOqOwnLeMREvC7sKMh0hs5BXwHxXGwwWbR52k31PsomNMUkfq8aQbDkcm9SbkgqdKp10pMrO4qRjSSJJyiTdUlA4mILIpqXQ99@0eZJVtDlCWCg7o2B4XFX6U/eKSnZ0lQlHJBNJ5f1RP8eTwjFPDSp9JNyHa1lFQkf3g@MqK1CqDQgyWTyxspDuB3EBG5jSrdCXQlRSjBuA/6pGqKbaxIuaj@5/CQqf@mFv5jv7c8j4Ojaipkp2DHLL2X@25zz/1Dl4/mI/iRotboNH4VJaYY9DMauGcXf0ki3ThI9n0WlbEvVnOvfcl1yNQr4N0Gg8tYDkM52rK2AUx1iWzrv3/ffOER3eEzMpxb57rCZd99j0odobz0bRu/fz9zy9c@L0qkQC95yLKi4J7i0Ni1qJisPW5MBvcQgLCb6yrd0qxLVwCtcyV745xsriOrXm3QuFLWf2T5o6Wpm8SccBOWmbxE4wBsuzreJb0nD0TuOAm/yW7TnFYrphOJSq1aXkknPXBG707Yi7ycquWUlpVSVbcSVCYQZPNUQc0bg21@mPnffBe11ZfKjg6N9MSztmtOG7WU2jdcTwskvA1I@tbHmVsPrczyV/LS04NYNOMt6oet2QBYEg7/Fu7gmNJ8CYvpfAzOagwWQBLcHxKkgAyjJZAuTyyxjb2a2Ml15GkewWx@txuTkraonRZRTJriVudHIq4rWemo3emLgzCUiCH20SBK3zNXPmiGyWKl61WJ10QUWKLM60pc6i/HEz6tDbtEAQPR7rn41jMb1xCnaxS@GTI2K3QHXeGhDsQexOBceand5Ip9tHkrNrFU9DWI1KARPO1El19VyIJ5FE0jkstWRZsdGWigYOXksdjbTlHFugTEIrQCtJUFk1MSyBAoS5OJwsFqisxCRoKRvUIn6Gt7Gm2mqtRgNayga11scS1koW1iRoKQ26tK/xRpkce8PQrhUvnzx3BR9ro7Oq8ud@bxbJSaOdVtAaimh52IyWgu4HJ0F0z4kZLf5VpfaAaDc2lUdsnUYC/u27hvXhAprVtpugqo0RYreweKkgo2K5jrLZt5gxN8xjAl5CXON93AI9Ygh7GhzxwKQaopkMJdDoU0yzYvbQSKl55LTYGMnJO7fe0ecFuN@jW@9E3JHI7/ly3r3IS7NaiV2U@qSTlXy0s6PHohqN24GT@a@lGs84xhMniaMaJ13yL4FjFplUXHGUh@OeXHaWgaulhbUjSocAzg87KRx4TVnuiy5IaI6vbgceVJZxoAkl57JO2Ti0ULWMY@3aOLTAtoyjcv12sDyV1ZePr41DBMEsHLVr4wAFLo9p/tY7QnAh/81nkVpiPGAWpVI75W6SNAzOTuKrm@6LFlUd2AsyhgT8PPWV1Q7FmNu0PrTEoGuNB4SO5fEoBrKSduko5p27LhfMDZR0l9aLCLecKjew1sprOR@FUZ8OgupgaNZ3xuJPieipSxKFkO89IMRUe6dTEpEwm1UlfWgGhHFS@9ttqGa123wz9OLg@fcOHjxtP3vwFELULdmjcH0DbRlW16lXm4hnL7ctbdYp8hyoWqAbOd6HrTxun0Kzz6cIR45FqVvvLLiLvDBQqMnj@6LqyD93PqUsDlq/hBOQVXM3Q9NT5DaYTT1feZt3Y0j7BNO9UvLaLrWEYYROVEsYxkrOWcKWlH89Eg2V16PXkQB2nSOxyQyP7fa@huGSVdBxKm9fR9/3p13oklSM01KZRajgQ3Zj51RQuVA36DEGawJ/Xas5D7VTXGW/1hn24PJ2NmDHt2fBsHPW7Xeqk9NJbhB6yj1NsTAI4eQyB2Wqx4f7By/bLxCna/8RW07gX4vzDh8/3X/@6hA5LylrXSXvHxw8P2izgvrBqxeH8BiaSsrbgApLDKYSEkDPnn/24IkFI9951UgxCAlJ3qQ/ypVP2Qkm7Tn/d8FmHmVRhWhzEB42U0FRTis7UXDmj2c6eBv8T@gDvgzLEzzKUF06qjE7pCni@lPlxb5OLywobsd0NokYlDXgi6mRcJMlBOYsPEEB9kUUEt/O2vRVuVFGHgz5xpNiqiwMZFAsp@y7BiGvDiyTl4tRr6jRKUee5Xf@iCDx2lSYRYPKZuHChVfJCSsNpQsXanRy1Ng5aiG7pBpBpZWes4IY2deurZw2eCcotijhSYgtU7iAvCC2nFIpcN/l7ABRKot2VYkf9c6xbOiTMCp@zQ1rjsStqej5Uv0gEPNLWeAYGpHPF/ajFBOYep9iY44jWJ6bMeO/urNyw1w0s1Pk96nYrrsK7ZFH1OAHUVEcvbDPvpju1HOXakAbGekZT@YRevU2pjrMFQqNh1GLBiqaLhyxIAwjM1zU82P8d65cu/agQFMkgnNt2HxecsUdJYyEwkgAWMzL7@a3Yzc2YpZgFIcFYseGaGRBfGFDNLMg3toQ61kQv/ypgASDYqmkJ2/Xad6@LdrMifnMKP7fTPFKRcPuaFXouDDhs4vr01iQ7AsOBV3yYA5qn9mE3G7ZnUtblkT9y/9OuG1cqlSFK5GGX9LsSzD/6u/nt@WG7hqj9G@kh9YGBeZEPXmJCTPuCx8pEtdNUrakaWx/eQm2fF7PYnbZP44p4osVRPPLv0rAZJPNz/S8O2b89AvXjbhsI7ZqSCP4H8sIvA9B0Jbyen2xt1Ex4EV2c9tg0T2IEQjIug3STINkVfn@0irrNr5GZpUNG6R@nSp/@deqTnV@ZUD8mYHgvVYNZibo/0osNFbNp0JZoKFAwqbmRfzquxL8JNkGu1gW@IsYOxc5vrzdv/r9dLvjkpnw/yCTOLmATV962jMH/j9cF8f6Shw/EhSVyspxKwhEqbQS4pe/iNshw5teZpctkl/9o6tL11eX/ntx6fiY39UHt3ANGll6CzTqQclMLnpksMn80QCYlIzWWMeoWXPWksNZrAzGkh1omGxlcZbMbursRWb2uslOIb8QBktzSfCvx4zRjkQYZNYo/s1WvsJw6cxdz@baXOmQze0Ks64MzGlsDI@jTHEspmc3JXCsJYSMZdQq11XM3kWOueBWpvATdqad01EHAVrD8aiqIoAE49r@2fjLAAfVtAY3F9Uvw1XS0DdhrRkBy3EexNcHUKigpiqnIqL7LXI7ADu93uxsNsQbmqfkKjhGqtXgMo4FwdHsLFQ4ceI@nAVD6oEHTi1mEUnMm1Ar@RQmVvpa1aeqzqp2ucpaTfTGq@yGjpO4bb1pMIm4Mm9ZFoDLJ2ZQqYpgx4LVLDwM1N8xInFF66n@PAlGftGCRxTXoGwlsF@EkielWkwZ6TGxcJShAfJsdpbA8E7NOOvGeJJTDWHxU6yXmxg5H3TjTH1ECDHWEUHoNJUPOnYtAyTKgmiaxNIsb7gySozoBZHnWRJio9yso6IJsthFEXuGNprlnQG7LWKjVsbB2Aw0zwJxhDF6Na67deodZZh2efm//fOf/ru8@65W02kcUycYdUhm4IgkMVZ8Ho5f6G8LPeQTZauYwv3vY9yCuu/3grMOItREFmoirhWYaQKB@R0RGpxWjYe034xPipYvGF0hCKtWe7C35xx@dvD8c1hDySUCU0GqOIhg28mXZNi5ZCJfKQYDRFHCMsxTVTGAdCOWoUyvAGZ6zO51BkVLA4tG6w/@CY8W3@WPoeku6zKFENl5ceqDe0Lo1tpozURoCsY8/ME/FszjiWjPZiMeT/KKMOnnxCfi11eRxaV@CUR2fX/zJ/@cq1MWJcTz4V7lzK56FdPPuUfqQpZpttI4XtmrRDU8CCsRXzlEf/gXjCyUIN16I8zdsHdFgyS723/2rx3GgccHmj2rpJPAU7oS0c8EkXk94JFbia9yJb4/Enz9gF8BbETdRbKLT@mcrE5hNFS0kmtXDN/f/IlqMcEHEd5MLqljLdHcXOZk/Fd7Zrmsmo5V82vhXznDf2ojVWauqzDKQZWJ56d/HS9Tu5viOlno@4a1OlNNy@zwT/9nFvWxjjmtHngAF7T2VGWulRVt/pf/yuCf527MryCYv/3zn/8i7uN8Zc/mK/vz83g1zZd7MV/V9hupLekHODLypfnKqfirZDWJlTv3rM9VCP5y1bjPk4M9X7XkifTNop9fsexXIfmZRmIW/PzKJb8K1x9pXJmLPd2tFct9vnKZa@wrFnoK/9qKZtJi/C/2YpxfNvMr1/xqsvi3jBwMH4xHl6alVlMcTp1Z2x2nwX/hmRd/d9OtsXc/XLXFjItHHBWhg9SUoD1AzXfslf8uHVP@QviaOLWhnC3oHlm1NFQtJJp0hmFGVZ73rdXVxNCRuJdRy@7XqyR3UauNfDG6n036kDr4/e6MJY8pP/8heED2zvj7PJfEbZO4ItY27J7giJt8zC844RL5AB37HNKiBjxA90nc4L87pruVhqSwvHEjjWU4FpboBl@nQxRaKYgoSaLUOM4UKkROzVwI/8nsQCJddUW6wmCpPrIf2Tjnys37D39hdiQzSuMk9hTK0tU4/6OaBlYx4rdy9tiheLrVqL3ElxGkkqn6CFh5dP9ne7dIVbeal7TAVmH@439qDjo/hC5rn/oDk1f2@I/gmBiYlSegtX/KT0ZQdNfiLWNlzf9MT3woO9SqynGSXaOeFdX8xT/Mg7SzB0myW1cLWQrjShnLefzMefVy/8B5/urwxatDXMjYjhGNDL5a0BOxW/ZlFmCTlwRLsmyLxPymiLNWnpBXUA5KTZe7/y9@ju4L2pKXr@etYbq03J8myjV0uUvGiKfi2iOkxmepvFxaUOukbtVbz9tUI0QC9ONRhPUa@vRDgcnFhDh8VmebkL@YTNtSt6pY8Fxj6r/NblmXMasvE3DUYQK8hoP58@rfUcZvhzL4ymqB1zsv6zVP8FMvtMtPBv1tU1DiZjP7wvf8/Lw6QHiq2TSo@iHcE4VwDFebnBCzMBrzpSbcZhPhBT2SbeG8cNZ7E/@q9Dqjt50QCjL35lCJ9rY@Wcjf3Ko74snJmYTi@Lr3xI7Dt73lRblXJmTlbu9NeXDeb6kMMQw2CieSCO5nqj/OQv0rmAwMxDjCPbvJ6g7f9MZD5nbz3SEdZPm4aumhhlzoT/U9CcQwRl8iL5T3U4eZ5qIoUjh4NOAc@klclbYuDuZHi@NE8bkpntBmCSUi5qVIRSEY@aLHwWED5pI/jyvV1R7NlbN4Y0KG1wcohWhIoFlomIRFOHLmohS/ixcqpAFykUiD5U/P49J6vOWL5tHThEE0MaEB94u1oy9eH70@HoX@@dpxqXZShqMjQHeVWSOPKfvskd8Y/eHb4WQcJpJGfhiJgktdJ/VOFTUIrYjiixqrlMYNNcso3ATxoEE70ONMbNEPomKgzFRZG@eUn7fzR/l4jKVhR6oxGOlAKxmoNDw8Wab2NqJjCxHSTZd0JL4sXaj851P409KwFRpzOIAZLWBGiEANyaWiYpg6F8lW4bVMEmjYxQduqis6n6biKJVldfNCzb/d/Jsf3PwBrYvs1jPByqaYUhqb@7Th@mq5iEfMXc@aV2pBba0zhMu//P6I3dNoxUG3tVbTpilSD7qggs5ak99TjifkJXWktFBQ1wKyr7PwZFnKutBDajRN4ld4zteEoMrLBiIRRDKK@arY3C5Gkq5sHPwsllXs3GrknBs5lyICPV/RyGNVDIE8bbcNx3Da1qHziPA1RKOXxUIn7LxFfCpxRbRWM3XGew5TgbYwpAkFnfWOM2s/shptbVopBCDEJQR9f9CZDaPtXHrDa1TMl9mjZCj1HiVfigxkryAC4y24JUplRUNk6sUCV@kBu72kX0e5fKNcLzf4f3X5f76sE/X/G8uJ9SRkI5lYL6f@9xtJPMbIZotFjfoGNuTcr285k0V0Oh41c7ccc2Y7fGbDH6G8oH4ZyvtwOAomEz/iMEfOiT/C4zYCvwZj3FjA@Rfi6tDvNz77F9nWyB15im1/GbaBqK0QVScLJ//R/TyN@9lkPI2cr4ZBV/9GjPI7G/orXIRwIxX6PvNAITFB6pkb@r6H08Xj6PkI9xI1eEyOxvK7Oxx3a2ckyvtTduUY0poniGBcnc5GNXY35Y/6eBZnM4TOG2raKVVHXeu3CayNbhVdUF7owz1l/vV8MMiz8xZ/2H/pg3HD7ZFjIqk87jPf0QlP89jWbjnPiAnbFncr2oeJ8dLFI@47BfUYVxlKPGfWGChYkb6g8Y5YlqyZkYdStHqvZ9d/@So/QFOpvMtsWdHlE3EcxfBalVMVEMWQRAn0EUH6hDHGWRH3CCFCfViWqEaUHEclcDviT1VpnMAVqfM5KBN7iF5pK1q/SNMqPGNjG@49cVfmNVyzUwSwk2psbiM2B/cEA4ppUk/DjU3ksIPK0EHEOfFNY/ej5KmWEKBMCAdCJB57Co8M3S9ZiRSXdXR4gP6qOg/XE124RBtyjBfcX438E46S4px3AwkF0w9CBkDJ2slXwUQNUTlBqt3ZCbHavBY4skoQhjP/9t3NDW4QxzXSoP1xLwHarBFmuJatceNOo7Oh6cVWdOoM/bf@UPy/SbM59ossSqazoto@cd18x2XSoaFM9JRGobhVlrS9/U@fPDjc3ys7lcZtgIuBqoEtWoMr2SXOZwMORUYoIsu32r2zIUReDMuF@7WCq5p@3x72kt1gjYD2rCnkuEmx4HExdTMniElk6mOvKpt4iya2G3S1sdzQlNkUUQvyenD1yr91Kw@SRl23QIKJzZHKuPGhQV@08SwBrdwraATU7taGEIZQQky5@Z2blYpZU9v8q0Iba6WyK3bm@Uckh79xCgezUWK3LfDa6TgF2uTgLU@2tpsF3heq@ZZz6hU@DgstcOeGc3pbnLnvdIi/0QCtKMrAHY4fLvT8FWdaa4UGxD1qHLuuSij8n/9NYt9FbBYwLEbuO/DXX3naJWxVNvV98aBZLMhtMBX7qhr58@gRb66RF7VMge64v6hySNL@Izp7@8Wv7DomRfcdazf3PG/dfUdVTiewQ5nQZugfEka3hbRBIi0WOV6/HsEt7hrkrx88ffIZTfkB/EuF0dEXx2sf1cqFAh3xrIHkIdKHs/f86QvcJEzdKt8ofDodn6lxmXZMJVU87MNymFtfzqNrNaxC2jlP/Ej1Pny4OOycPOuckcTcoSFIXuB0bK0fhLmHLr89Rl4@Obl5992Jx1CnU3/QEk7oIvTeFk/cVkR/Tu0qblMVXrPJ2CMq5MGBQGrUgxGd1p8dPn3iFXY6DrB6GauiUOoa4iBCYYIpIokF2gTpIJwuqCoSu00mGPpXKuR3k33ZqXV2C62Li5XteTLu9MXjVyEm4H5xVlYUN/WWp7Q1jalgMfE9JMjR9r39w3yZykL2RSLHOFrwpiXOiD1dh5Abdgo@AhcvAeN5G598wmkoMgs9r1mvu1APuSBs7AOC0MrCmrYuph2vXzQD2ZkEVb469@dSFzMnzWqz1hmF58SO1hp36lvr9XvjKd4N@n7Y@ySkLcTrIKRsEC0@gSE/q5OdjIeDTwbBEA9WNzfWNp8HD//uD7Ze3tkr9rq/Rzxk/stwjAf86cRuwLRzrrT/aI@d9oS6uBEjwtnr1CadN@PaRr/e26xvNu72/bu3/c36@mbvtr@@1d3a2uoNNja7/a27nbu3e90a3EZzkeoZKw/mhfxR7eB61a5izDab9a3BoNG4c7d/e2uw1ayvr290N2/36xsbg81GZ339Tr@52d3qXs61xe3J0Qar912cHekd@OPVzF1uaW9XpV3cvH0e@NO@7e@57HT6nYkOUauI3NgJ6mhqnSj0F8SS9WrBvMY42sXfG5@O2o/Gw85JMA46dE4M@VGf1YLxc8E/4ajpZDo@Dx1E2eOMvgXUX8S/Yy9R8q14QnzaBl3@RAnQ@lZo8QA8SrFeZokI8m/svQSho9miMXGZYcps3I4LxU7B4teihttaWXa9kVVYhYs0WhIcPjbtfwu967Beu6WulQboXgZgtbHrVJyOu8JLYqLFWzREfHeQaLFujGX8stwJjiS9qkFH/Xm5z5eFEhd7zz@Z@n5Y5OQyFYNY7NxzturOtorJrotyxOz@HBeG@LFYPdzNu7/j1lMDvkHzG@tZ1JJFCI6EWpbVECg5QO4xOtQWdskIR6NlcJkkfYynwUkw6gwTSNleLoE1mb1YNRoc18@5qa/zlqiSHRARo4CXhCLMNtsLFwrmBafgpk3lVhCsf5XPUl78VE/Wm4bV6FVDRfyWl39dz6dcmtpNLju9a62YZvO6s5YaQC/LzV/itcUXh50qDLnIz@FsgtsBv59PjZ46oQswxylcc/RW7h3Xtgbrue6VzleF2Lx5qbnW56H1Fvi5aOXS7UkRTXLEOI4k0RCsGvi3IfP0IM69Ntab115cMQ6rxix2rmoOFTPffVn7OBTfwouqPmjMkuK24zWhZdKP2tTx9uodROGUa8E27xhtbBnthfy0UKWGyYzS9UeIqU@1PTUefRo51NunsbPnZ@Wg5lIjqd8mdFbiNlrFOQ4RKIP2pckA0kTR1Zc@ZpPiAxk3SPPyggMFNCoQ5PoSpVxePccjvxJH4JLHz3iyUnSkorWz7UsDOxEMXRJ2Lkb01QPWQvS@SAcmZ@va9kLUGYFpbjBBqYp9Tl6CSSVxgOv2XBQ600NBSzxjKGJJMb03nV6/V9@0Ly0OQK6ibrJ7TfGuWi@jMy6uxE7pP3ZWm3X84qpUyaSNe2IhtHlroLXgkBQxlNCPzP2xIRhNKP0oqmXk5pR9GEc9KqkSxPGu36mb0UaReX/BZllquGW1uU5lV4rEBCXfGH61FIXVZQdQsd8kKu81CAPeH7j1uG1DFKwE5SUaquaICnoNLEtK5OcLS8duOR@DqqOy3rYg6lkQWzaOSiYSYiyyYeKGEM@SDRJjoYMusy0WxN3s/sQQxBCbcOc84jQValaSY2hmTgaQfnJrzY5y1HDKdUXBnLlx201kGvrm3K26lVtP59L4mBYeVRrp3M16IjdRLQ1KIjNRksbDtWtNZNJQuHaDza7wzf6xO3BbN0FzuDuWkJHgMlT8HYjLzjnkNhIznR0OhKN5DI3PjsajxS8E/uKYWJb2xOWaEg4UJDYLrDvyDTtru6ZAQ/RdHoJ5af/iRZEHmWHN46TPKxWT@FUljKrW00p0SjtAMOguqHj4xl/U6v7WZn@j2bhd97t3NjY66xv1OyDhQTAnobg@32863dnJtUOE52ajMDgZsf91tkobvcVzbiqVSV/RB53sn1A9G0ROOztQweUz971Or9/l9I10Ogh3d3c5fX2T09eZ4Dggr3Kbk2rDGoK0SgiyNu2DEtMtCRKMwlEZDw1E2QoumOj4t8qFRakUTIwDCrhzA9qjYHLMjRmwnjFeO9I59QHHUbTcVIwSRu3zen1bXNNTaVerBFj5DcrnPoCLYtR99SxynAHdNNCVa0CvE3QSCO74kJIBvGFQG8zHUioD@DYBA6lHpzL8ZmUC3RGgyqVAdwkoYEwY3hKuWpZgNgWmomGaGTBbgEFgau6DeyXOzjL8pfi7Cv6a6HtL4Jdi72fNVByVdbmATwV0CNhkwSzoQRZ6qPIWwZFQ/sAqJJrzuZwEuQ5GCA@KMr2yWnFr2CTl1EN8VSojARXDaS9eYb0OlliDo3MoG/uMhYttUeIUEmTDxJlGbZANmlZoxOVYv3ImfBw6qP71KF92pGUay01EVof2Al9By3sm7ez5ad51L0U80o@LHJuNHYThLYerUGhcO0ojV4LZ4lDu2MU5cK5sJzpgLM1ZU20NPGzNRKEWq083dcxdawoZeD0DeD0LmJHAHSsROItYTRyq9LWOaxBEpIUut/Nw2gmGQ385QLBEypbNHqgqjAmRwLFDEPGg3ors264VhxqzzdG4VbhgNbk6CqVs0oDawdOxKskkSWVKJdBjz462iwCQIVNovN9zmNpPcONxQ58FgleCOeVuDDgingyRChTKyy8Wb6AV/n8B';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<=oC<=oC<._>>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]>84576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t};prescata, 847har
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>          K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@   A=AgRA;       AC
#   /         
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[x]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#    ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+ /.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=#x=2;  print( size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:√2x==2?201:225)#s⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint ("65" )#`=>ass#
#9'>+/' 25  pe+--[red[ ]print 221;};]pp^pppeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*ss<s*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///\)Q222999612#
````

From Julia 0.7 [release notes](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md#julia-v070-release-notes): "Numeric literal juxtaposition now has slighty lower precedence than unary operators, so for example √2x parses as (√2) * x".
So 0.7 and 0.6 are separated with `√2x==2` where `x=2`, see line 220:

```julia
x=2;  print( size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:√2x==2?201:225)
```

Comment: I think maybe you can replace `==1` and `==2` by `<2` and `>2` (reversing the test), assuming that doesn't mess up Brain-Flak or something.

Answer (score 4):

## 226. [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10683 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bc@NMdiD4LM7@g31JgfqKpHgDeBMvIlXUraQqlaTSpVRVFD8WSIIkJBBAAaRElkpftHs2et1jP3h6eh1te8df27Pe9e5MxDg29sET44mNGL9OOOY3lJ82HBvb/6D3nJMACFKUSvV1O3Y2YiARSGSePJl58uTJk7eDpmz3fv3rIF7s0NDGXc0YsIFiD1jbUq8UK8HWx@yprNrZVDoQQKiq1R32FX1gFwNBJjGm6i21De9sYFwquvpRscA/xZhpGV1L7rNBTx4wxW7JpmIzYzgwhwNmdOZHSzO21Tcu1DjG7Kt6F8AGimVayoDCM4yd6prcb7blmZDsTIKmBeE221S0T/1PA9Yy@n1Zb9sAmWPspWHZCsK3FNs2MPoKY6MtpTWDNA@gsqUae9X9ZzNBBcaeQRZlU1NGTG7aA0tuDVRDR5qI7Hj/9PhwJoYksdcn29uzvin2Im7obHvYupwNSrNTy5Y1eRZ/hlWHA2N3MOufZdWuossslSgkUrOBObZuyXeirDBLkdsdVVMSUCEsznqKZioWQx/WMSy2C1nS8mJebFQnMRMtjJufBM6iLTAtnR7MlCclAuENq6fokENxNlDyAmcCUl5AW6UEZGvMwnbPsICPLDa0lTa7Nqw2MJeujSMxiM9GH1lTtpVcBhGkPQSXunGtAxMNDKja5nigMN3Q4xQZATNM2mvMMlYqi77Vg91Z/xxL7c36rQCjtS47d@sylWdHhjme9S2wl@rePHZOi7whbBhtqI2ZMIkdyuBFyUwTPp2abgUtqF1ozOzChoy1FWbrqmkqAx4IvKJYFAyxmabql4ghzc5UxWpPpUnt/tAy2sMWtslBT4FgbMfIJnagBcgqzHSkRwIdLEiMxcEA7bHRV/wobaYrUG@2qbTUjtri/KaMBopuQ0nsBFOhbNeqprG2okGECfZWjNkG1vrEq6nJvUQrEUB@xVRY/1JjKmuZJuNBUDjI0raYZwoSlX2EcK1ns5HZZ7bah@BBy@h0FIV9VMweRA@0jQCDq2XOFMt7W1IARldc0igmyAkkjYEVAHRyKXRtyUBxy3ZoMFD7QG91ELKZItsqylmIYit6m6hqehLYYPJUS2BXKsgBKPrQIty2YlFLJLzQai0FUMpe7YevLXUwoMbEquxQkS12YilKZFoaTyUJiRmYwgALkqBKXV0NbR1sh6ByeYyEbEJlWumTV88DMkuU2VKjBL@yIJQCW/ub7GbpHN1c@AIDmFZYjrDyd8xOnp8r8BtJzWTXug0A1gBQRWNJwxwk5bgJGYwPIINJGZ3oil@lEqbmS5itztSFj@U4VBtqA2QSex2jkrWGloUdzISo8iUUWjP0LtATCmsNdaSHznIiVEHLgP4hxpQroBoIZKojEBdI4ZOeCpVmY5X42hvvJomg0FECGzsUddO1DW1IcBDTHiAvA1UgKmLc7bDXrCOrGkaBcETFc20p9lAbYJyh3saah25QaSeYmw1qxxbw8RUkJwNS8gDW7/vaJWUKgKEiDCoqBn3@gz9pd7uAp9pqgchz2PU1axst6tBlyiz0kgwZFuSsRtkCuBimzqNDAleyprZJbsj62EmCMkGpXhtDrc0MSNC6VqGV9uQraNnQuFoDhTM51wFirC9fcmmics6FgvflJlQsJUBpU7Hj7OkG1FJLCQSJZ@L94aCTZ3Fzi4Xs5LfhtWJ4bfFcgcxFEpHlpWSyWwKGSyyTF7yFHuKc19UpAWoPZNtQ2wFzPOgZeorFW0xolQ1T0cOhKRyhWMhqhiIJlHLhSEkttxIdVW@HQ6vAixVIOBQptcqtmlqsl2ai@5MENNeIBpurEm5FhACIHGoUV8k@CPkE9Bmv447LF2bYDSQ5Bid83kiYWb8r7hEkHQj50kAGATmUsDVFMcNiQoqgmEC4ueXGgHklncHhFLio1qOhYCjqLzphgJJOFRQb64lqoNjSzB72ZUAU3TahJ7CQd1vQgaNktNUBKKIx1iS@pl4EJAvJxGslZCnY03t8RE2SNzmMH0dB6WCYNKHplqy0fQ0ZhAC05YF9RxprxjUkSHnCbgZEh46Jyl2oGojMC1LlBeEpkc90kbj@AdiaCsvHmyo0AmxuINMdnveVDcDTKQ4D2Hgj8cmevjwGLC3erU4aDFM70Jb6IB5ASWopKHNA@Ci8Q8FEhtT@bFC9UQkX46lsdrqN3WliAytZjb8DIf0x@WBLwsL7GxMKGtZRrpkm692h3FW4gsbkVksxB46ggpLYAxBFs/0NecadzjNh9wJLT2fTpk7EVS0maaCQ57XndIUyShdH/4@DlqMw2RnBgEJpgVjSxrOpA8DVTOLCewSZysB74Z4suBoAMJkyUlrDAUg1YODrntrqAc9i7nQuF3knNJs8ePlTB8ke73hJY2akypNUIJH0vDAb96KIY43exQOdK6KqTHlQ5fs9HsYs2/05iA0vi9AR@HwTSTkBvPcFnH1DN@YgBUJ6aBFkOoTXA2hix6hQQsflql3UWD0t06siqDMcH7SR/3qDgWkXoZ9QB71hMwGckjyxxruDAx2ZJTmwxurA4O6mZjRBLNvQPpNuCsnWsKmOZgpEfl4dXtiBK1DAOjYrQ8/9YQhcFw51bBCY5L@BwL4ggQQ3oeB3AQAJKAGECndsEsXbIFSOx3orLEwxpRBjArZdAQZCAkb0SPMclbfpbF6A12wuEcyfmUQSoZK21SJH3KeTInoEp2wFFqaK9sg8BhYEAW4dWbMVeOpDTcPXoc6lXJjrChF2E1hYANEWpuTUvqmpLXXQcGYTnjxx5xUWy2VSmzqoM0UgzoIzyE@AQAEYp/vh0ImBcUzKbjgCBVm4nUpYsSzD4ukOepZxzcgDwQJ@om4YfZTu7IwULtSgYZSt6jg0c/pS6krluSqE16eSvhwKJS4MVQ/fhBYXF0PFUAV6zMXFNXCtomsNXVFwrZErTi6ES6CLYsTIhaE1ioF@9dBtzcU8itSxOYywt/@ommG5Viym6zG5JjnPFD4jQGfoMQA6jg/AE4qUy@iMRITKNRQ00exMl34De73jlqWaDhGey1cyf3eokCYyQMXhqN1SSqi8PEyTftkC7QIGA61e2Aqd18Tz@vnNeTt6fhuKYexISS43oVCQXrif6FrGENSQSC1TjEv1SKSWBuWjWQ6JoeVwOB/XICE5EvkmH4nKnNrhkAK9Yfj8PAREdehTa/UswjeKpSIRj1SQD1R4QNcOhxI3eUi/GalHoiGIGwnFYOhWDoWAMi0kgk2FxrY0RaCDoxecMBvRaICat2Fd4u9Odwp@CRi48ujbIBc2jqdnGfqX0Guxlq2hihe3uJYHr8ll7tmmh6fJFtkujQR0UGOgBKDFtL0RJ05@YItzBw2GPyEaZiME@WGfjv2VOgWDiDvqCAZeIE/HroKJehHqmBswkDc0JXFGbU5gIC5wlkFJzNUyD3l3nWjZEx4AfRKcpia3QKpMozsX2DkgBD5PJueHREp3EM@qoDRa/FIZocNuyTrSr63SaGio2j0kL2isKGusDlAVh0KgcylEtV3WAl2qC5RWRuqAj42Aj44xyo5shyOojVe5NotKNGpimCl3boXUJKMF40gFNDIM5YNytqVfqZahI5ETW4AaGL6EdTCDfB55gY2q1d3U5v30nYccKHbHW/LR1o91lrgtu8WSuqEZXYMtAwCyZiLBGXtXx5kp0KUHMGxntvqRCFTtGvp4hgcVVKNs1L2lXNob1cgImST4xAXIGja/0BOAe8p8vPtuCzo7KSuKkH/3TaTLK6QPy2wZ0bPFJgDODLmGfIM1@U4xe@Op@TvkDz46B34yFN4w@XyJDIoK5Mpp4R8pqr@Rcx9o525Q23XNK/sWaZ44ReQfvU2VfqpP5M0GShic8UZflxRTSO9U@KR@UXCdJ6fkljcgjXf6xkBOvk70bIa3AOphcZUJdjK0GErG43gXKIilKizZVq6SKKUczCCVT3pDJaC0egYTzkEn9AMJIEJ7MLiJQyGgx0ZF0ovmrAUEBsYQ9PC2oql9dbBLE5SajspmguRgAgWAE4rTrxMEh6oCGhQfIU4EN04iTqS43uXwRyAUCSuMyRK85JbSTi7z0K0RdoR2QKEn2z/Y3GocVk92ykJyaFtJTW1Cy2krjT4MJDTFFtjshQlAUk78j5fakWEMypxNLjX2xSuIcdzoe5uNvd31o@rRW54JQmOr/aEmY1aKSzMAGP2YgnlpDrT29NwuKd1TYyKHqVGDLDHQtFk8Dvc4@lFqpGMmMAA7fBTD8TjOack4a2exlCQWCu2mnM8ruXYrk1npyJ12O5OS8tlOPpvKinBbyRUU9onA43FlRONQcPExHg6HMQ3IOT2kRMbJkpiVm5IyN1M86IFsKe18K5/Nykoz02rJkKtWLq1kOqJYyCiplJJpZjqSLKVSD2aLp@L266Dmt6CfHs/NkBf6QJ5a2ayykinIhVahUJBTK@20nMqvKEpupZMRRSUniZ1mXsqnH8yTLxuoUEze@jS6hgaCAzEKnIh0PwNYRt8bZttOW11KY@tUptb3cM7JCc1g6NBZ3fP559C/jyt2iVag22qxuMFfPU8HcAUBcRWPFKhuNIqQtKrneTqQeUKJK3sJq@l6FtDTW9ObWu2aoJsXfn8kB/ONJN4iclsf2qavZDeSRP5Xg04HVUbPO0Xel3GUs9rEO03efE1wejXOIcudoLnAHr4M4eNriXPx3QmaC@zhy3J8uAY5H91MyDxQD1mOkOGa5VxcMwFzAD1MK4TJv845CctT2H2LnE5ac4PvjeThLhBuXAidoKJlUcfLBUxx7ujzRUq7gQsfEx5JSVOhGMSXNlm8DUP5VQRBfvmEi57gBUMI22wnBqPBBEXajyIOCi9f8vTCOSNIWkNuQKuc5Nb18QWxuAZ9nJSbRM56kY2ZqIY68fbAeb2mtAaIgKGvSbs@/iAvEq9Cd23V3yhSvAYtwxz72vJNihO/rzrixNe60pzcJIdQNbemAjm1TXd9dSqMN0u@ptq44DPwDWdJ1V9laU7va1xHpaEgCcgT0Af3DNDi91SbdkD4JWbAG22eBwR3yDw9aTIJSU2WBFj8av5ahuBHRJ0HiNtLAzvkiashJqQsYvFQ9C@1uzE7MOCh2xTonUzdDeGKRL/ZodscAFRyZmehKICm@BytCcZFcvKIHjjZNy8H09OWU8k3lc4QxmLJpqqj@wtg8UKeIDvNpnofKFACF6nd5xywIjsawng4lcgkJHfwjcsE0IfyOceT3QMChJbcuzPXzaaIPxhaA4jlPP/Tj9pQCXerqCePaUTqORq6ck380bm3xpyo@EK3@bXL1bOhpspEGHJ9CWVLxuVFWfMc81FT7cfjPdnq48DPqW5gULwBJzzAazznlqIN24r7nJ9IkRGRp@fUma72WWsONMHOTP/zxGiorxlym8jAB@SqQpEsrGxeDcqID0196jCIpfsSmjNLzybL4oPecDDkd1wJ/1I1qib@HmqiaUfXTBq23FSVB@rbki@HbSNuXnaptJin3BzYScGbOOsZ72jyJXc20Dm/5LxsltrtKpb7vA/sugeDSxoVJ6/p8QBLuNoVo0GT/BBOS@P3@0DcvWme4346qRrdHlHDHicRb4A@TaTFfS5xH5nUGcJqcnOMswO9r2cpTJDUVhAw5VY0Kqaxn/UWNSc7akzz/vjYOVP8QmF@bL7DhpNk3tg1yXfWxPnMKJXZ2WvzhdYNvZTal7V4qu1z3iu@3Vn3iWsOKE0VxVuabAMzDZzqUK6g@uj2EINjN9RCtpq4HmDvSXbcte37lkkdGeU04ZahqTa2Y@0@cTm7sjRJE/c40W0SFd/uErZNmrDdi3uu@ZLAaA1wjfIeRnuESOPLg7gA6@OchHEf0VrGNf7u1SN6xpXC7/N7tY9zc/UIGRXXiCXU1tzuo936EqfiPhe6zafj5dx8DVraXH9n1Wh6NPBYXrZVzbDZMd0fIgUo2LbN7/O52E81VdbjtLjhd8@P5mTKZAlnMveeupS1rqHl8t2kDLd7K3xodVDyO8/HSjxPYknSlyWWqwAZuuQ87xX1l0nr8kucQCsgFq5A@5wP9LPzxJazwnZ/AWGogNtK5hduW8xTzESSz5HcVwFWq3ctj93nD@hN7qOu25uYY1KoQb/DCIU8OAYWV7J/SGqZh1NrP04k3UG78qVC@Cr3UlOg86L7nSplKVH6yhiSKD5eQHW0oTJU5sqng@aFgvuNHxhmPD5TolOMJWdKOQnEwwllD@qjM0B8VK6x38a3BwWMrKnQyL@o3cyVdyYo4SaOqQ/BcYiOuxG7@tCcqtypYZp@9DDleqbbso32VCYx5GslUv7LOtSUTm8r9LtvYAOZDNm4TxyGxkYflAedLwaC6AESqU1NYdcqkIrvXsFNqvbcmQGaCuH3qaTIZ6J6TM2YzMnQZHYaKle9tOM4T/w4@ZO6b1BPwIVCUocCDMZ4v4/o8@Rp0zC0r6kkEKttlY4YaHHcPf6lyrqj8Tibl9hk@sLGyY9m576JC97lOANMoB6OnQcPjJb9E1MPjPPuTLI/0HH5pty/NMaETpvmgnAzkOO@jzdpAkRK5BMrD7YvrpAaTUWT@WOUyzyEr5BIP4jPU0AcTZdW8XDlj6/1TZZhgzNSyBwDsdQ2DFN6Sl@h1wf0e7l9MbTdx71AIwN/c4ITSVqWuCeeqUKz1/E@ta7oU4wGhg4Dq4FsdRUcmWi4lO743idq3dWOucTd7ctdhZ9AekgWTmYmcFcrH89NnPPnKIp8Q1QLovH9Ig@zAjScS2Vsu8@5CF@OW1Cfw/6XZ9Zm2ngL5zy/2KgTybmLPF/Q/PSe0dN7Ss@ixuG93dc8gCMH/OzYQ4WA/Pdk@xK38ZI8mgzserafupqhaY@hLspDLh0NozM3X1t4BKcNUb8K71huQoDz@OKsHfTeRCTqxu9rOz1lCF2SbQwMU4nT232gGs778Pt9UtOdiX/M7FFTM2TcE/6Axg40cJ@PwdgyrC9OdnRlY2Ca9GiY2tCmG83fxulo1Ly62qacPqba1QHfkMSZU@kazVZP/VKWmoo80NXLpDtxw18fHIw6YpdKrrL4JnonNBVoZY0TWN1lf/gxPnbvqzPf0s3c0m8MLWv8ZREwvRnEm1jl6wHouC99Z1F2TjB17rjjzt1Z9sCihLOGey83kdaMGnJcEUH/kO6d9pnaXOjIKVpMvEe9mSk3Zca3fvY185XOThCauVN9e13Af96MxX0ib8eRZDAUDO8Mu3bky4zba4P2hLe5CKtdPDZps4FhMFszrn2zy9DhyLrzmNv/equNDy14ZB9c8UgknTXOuDK8d0pLU02b31m8k5qL5e6i/V2o8fzhrVM9baXDFyXQ9SUdrm9YeHIFlIV4y1LsFk5zo5zlmhEXObrRBXkb19gE2IWdW4S7@wTmaSHTfVn8zb7SlXHH5Z6Kmy81@273Bphntww8BvGroWyrr4bGQJmLc3brwGNQvpS7amtnqhZchC51ne15/DHVCNDrbkVc91SbDhC4jvkNh7MZrcLPGXLNzKR7B1kfnv3waUDOfmMW32XuvmTPgXP5GC7PTWtav3QW4O8VdOqAZkmd59xyzt9m8dDUwfWwbw5t5zE/ddqw5J8u7l@Sv32tghSMfwChy3qyNpg/peybMQXNyekJJ8779Ol3qmZ02bu8yEDRAgGH6vU9jLUO/fKhPIAWoM9hVkr/kauUOCERt3jhPgAjKGkWV3V18PDky2Agw4jHfWKBuFKFx92Se3hPPP1aDPGT@VTZe1DiQ5c@bmkwhvkS1OHbL0AoG1/uWr6w1gJdpaEPB3E8IvxQF5F7sIsoslE@5@MBFn619fI04rJCt9fi21y/oInZCozdhrY2nrjuXdqfw2EqWky4X8jejeEOAjaVjjzUBke4jPeYeFUTz@WQTN805g1WDsfQxXzViAd6iWF/U2nh8t@j8rBvvAT1DPotE6Rq/0jBhfoZQXJ/ZIy6Z7RkDWjWflRyx4R@TqcwGSvLptKEutcmrvn6133IN@WBPI@YCs77db40aC/ialBTsS64IYkHIe/mYEcZ0Sjjfu7hak580GpxjRqn0aYajW9kDXkxDT5J@UAuqtANfPXQPoG7q6c6tnjrUTQ@uOK7OpQ2PwtmzyP1kdI0tC/LFF3li/qypSp2ck/VhyPyY3HQy@aPYp6T5BC/MEtGQwBnZ41@Jdu0wD53cOJsPifDBt4RWDvmnDAAP9VyzsrZCdfIRZBOY9CBWHe/NgviMd0h6v0Dw0owgguH5Wg0EgnwSLhg2tUBzIUiMwN4BJlbMLAZiNcBwaodVquxpZtRUSxKt6zMhKLA6nWOFS86ELs1MslGwBGPXluS6@WlUDweWgqd60UmhjxwRQMNYi64PAXbUenB8zshAdNlfuYG3W6JS/yItd0j8wUwWm7DqPtUp/luHMHzg8L8FPoJbsX6279sO1YdugoUtq@CFg8EQaMmRl/pGddrPF0ndZCNMlqFQByg8Gn8jHJ8o8pAE4HhOTfmYFyz0@2TvHNE3LGgAi@HfPjm5YJXLk4F40GkAa88nhvvUImTsBfLLRT0e8O@zq7V9qBnJ0A80BmjoTXZrw0uBNMHFs7/tGNsl7UV3AhDR8doylMzjEva5o85@du/5Afj6QCZc7DHTZ4MYvhSxHNiEp1Gb7WMIeTaRfJRsQwHJIxEBvVviIsJDDUC8o/gsSo6sQ8cGXfPq1My/ND6RvWYxbdYCI3D4PnSktoJL1WPnr2uifXyd6yfVP7Tj5KRG4dwwjfxQs4WYswFKd0iY/mDsxA8CQ0xYWkk8AS903Wq059d8/oAEsmcyfCAnctjhmE6rYZsjpCJDY8bnaOrYXRTPbsH1/tkroQYVrmmFRw6e6Jjb4Z2QHQbGhi8Rgg1b3XlpfCQz3nHjwcsCwni4X8ZXNzACZ03w0PYGGVpxD6xHjIZCEspK8IbJ6SG5/775XV3T2Tav1c1uak0h7Rp6yqVSKXLVJylRnm1Qi6Qwwba36h9ez5KifHz0cpWPWm7RD0/H30jpt4A1Q0LYj1JYsvb2t@8WUpUxE@fbHnMBOE2VOJbaUFMLN0c7h5uHZ9UT06PoRZuXfGzzU88uLIGuYhONfUMjSybAF1QCn@F/PHe8JxxmC3JbBVNeUUiAf/BGQJ1aC3EhSXu9ImmqdhfiD4vvq34wu8CODKtozKXo3ahx8A6BGZDqmHhhybaZ2FOXMfGBHGZijIeG5BHGNywPEeWEqkEVgZixYFYjyQVu7@wa9zvMRT7IpaHybY2FwQp5qVX88J5EeeS4Pa3Um4TOsrfvNwcy8PlJpgHyg2gnq8bZ7u6u3d6tDUdDXiMniR1y4Wsc2KMC2dsaXwd3DWqQYd6nYi4XlAWmEAR@KvTmZGdtqYyuFagWI5wbPV5ZOJQyr8QmDAmUKaMxu7qJU6LcJhygDpICYs1c6Cto458WXT7aB@6G15ETwhsCx5qN@MJwcEcJAtjCbzcYiBWh1xu0zskIe7I65DtV39ibovDomEfPbR5m7unq/J6HZvBv69Xcl2pOhsxpzuT6izOUvDTFL0LBXZhIyXeR7ElTghhiedd8PKL1q0gT@0LmSbzaE@tc1wLemlNNtGUjgO9bwyUIvswNOhgsitMPP3iGqeKZG7Ijaq2JWNp6MCzPkCzOG6/Rfh2t4/LqJ1x1Yzku5/nhjp2VADkM6u2hSfTgNn46TZuoImT3HBsAbldJW1zsB3bH56WYLMr1aZtEFgJHdRxNJCUWBqn4GjqkI6ks6pmg07Shu6bGwYk5SRBRzr4uY64zoQg8GTCUxljTAggrF2@axsGutJrGAm13vPISwRHmG0fztDqYjwOlOuqumuar4i2@mj2vsgG1hD3T1VCd6K4WSiSK94b9DUf4BwrWedK8vMf/Am3jHU@APdPHfdIXIe333PeOuD@fTdEkuDtn3tvKXj7GX/7NolVdtcckJO8M3dx70EZ4Munwp0yoUxw7RNSWbzaxpp@vXvIbFpJw7rsyyNfNaGEQZ6DARfwXx@Y4orqGMF5CpMqnOAJ114DiwBfAX@geoMaDaWnWPUwGoUpJpOYcZzuS9CZCmXEl9HIRsyHIdpGAyUsmcvmMlISMhm/chGSQYEu7urnCCORIsjEwJVqlt83W3hsiwl2S9aUcq7EeSO5JH@bFt57GV0C2AAfKNQYxMGTXl4MCKs40cJLclSKYFTsyEJSCGVa2@CsBtpgmBwAEkFv3T03Deqm4ZAK@FhXRgPSmMbuAKiJpjFx@l/hFvJcRHFAxHGjBa/Z5jjZro8nmXwNNOGvBuEMwY4RrCjMY9bat@x8cK7XHUtuDBjvl3NYVwf3P5tj3o1zFppYuGtXLDxrFQxLw54e6wYO/rchtyycSqbSSSkX8XGo4KCC/GJT/wQooXGDsGgp6oVh2tWNrd3nB4fHd@xjEWRoFizEQpXV6Hk8EavVPUfIy/c0Ude3k8cv17ddUvpzNdnuhBCTPU@z2ZyX2mxO70n9jJ@TuJs2BdxJSBIfi5g2GMS3aXfgXeyT0KQPcINv076Tajhyc1urr1bO9eCd5D/NsxkYTCwjc4Hr3CaLgaHZbGIWd93THydoothOuAf8UsLEIqZ3fpG/T7zvt3DlGTyemLlyz5kEyJzBxORB4p4TKFD2RJInRbaIeMbc/IKscbMqYVYnCbYCd7as@XPDnLLctc3sHMb0iHTA55Bcy7o2h7RJOPNZJrI159HMgztxMWLTnxhIciwD9SB3mtoMXDtGLNyjrJ4Bi4RtauogHAnoDsTsoda7kPaDdoY8MLlcGzHvFKaNOuMoQcsgYTKPeF0PcDNNzLWmFCWDTIdDoNuhYbLJLNqm4rqOQKdim0M@La6w58M@wHXocaRgb6GAlhWHyEDPkJuVGpogciiR6Lez4VEk0VNGbbULPU44EgPR9I0kTUw5yWiLCPSq5rwS4LSU2ZOhDFg16VW0hDSKrBbodVJAPvXIrud76/UAIMOozUiRz1yETnXXmiFWfJGFYh5lmpFYKMH4SMoxVEi7UmkiKsE2erhfmaY@Oh2VVDa/gRTemXdUq5/AUkE3w1noGZ5W8HPNV1nV8lFGrskJVW8rozAaMCnWkU7gH7o@uwpFhDssTqa9HENO7VkbX64slAeOUJrYx5qRd4WCJ@emRUOhgEZQ8DwvDEogxeOBtQdOUBHCnb5ssvCQtu/aLMHoNXwe1mP2wIqweAW762ums2iU5jTgQQEwZkHQDrlUskYTRlut4WQZKgl9bb2Nj4@qyWpSIlEHNyUSYUs4n7kB2hTOBEYCMEaFKEVCC/oF/BUxR9zgdsIxvL1EyQbIThFDC2xzgklO4YoXyBegBZWaVZ747LtMBAynaqFQdGpjWtoXGPDF6hyBCGjnSHF3jAD0dY5nAtVQRgPUhqW0VZCXT18ouq4AgYBn@mhfXB4Ck1mRmGv6PjaxQUspBHkWd5zznpDRadu0W6EbDReSlpIlmhor3YJa8/4c9ZqOo9mMk/9tMpEs3YSXtPI4CbpmpBJe6pWlaHo5Gl3Sl8NLOmpbT57gjNrtEihzjQQMUEcAFF/SIiXgZ1D@ykt6aUleDS@1y6lligGvMES@gQjf2cnEzZJ8m1x6AspSDHwsLnTCSzaZNxMTCekW8octZCkZA565QTtdZNAek19So1HMQ2KpgRn4Lnl@HKVu8/w4SZN3JWcskOz2neY2o4p5NXHHED8noONd9DqsLHZYzr7dhgs8sUybnhd2j/rHE36BBx0YbdVSbP/gS5gOebxgceQ0ylxHyIS5fTkg4CgMRMTXmByJgDD59a@DUo4xYS2XDhvRtaxYioayEgzTYXwdfAp6eHJZsISb8834FVM6qdyHeE3uJD7UDy8PD99EzsOswELBjQNBygjf4jcHHnetsNQ9F/vhVzC4nAwEk8vSk5Vk8v379zDigKtWSVRAfPArUouH6rXwCmOVlZXlWC6/HHsaaviyFQmnUpFjpqpJdq6adrsNP6NHX58IB/m1tkZpwfAf/hn3c9J3HO4Lgji@wa@Eu5KzQXa@IsvL0UzqqV5KpMTU3/714m3s5rCx@re/008qi/g4wMdPb1@i@1jKfrO4@M36eiYTA0Jy9@G7w7fVajWzGcse1rJrmbi4uPof/8PiYiq1mkou1m1bqodql2@ElJgREn/756HDw1cN2wZCFPBKMwmceM/DT2LZLLtkH@G67DD8J/fHts8to7vZ@Yg25WC8UiZhEwpl06Hjb0Pzq22RSZW1lf/884MPwUGwkkqeWfAcBD8Ec/kgd4ID3tLu21WwElxFsNxtcJwsl8vgXPnP/xbiV54DHgwZr8KtknVx5cbBSrxMUT4FKzlwSKkUpPt//ehHgWBlFPwYlCQpOKa/Brrhyj@RnjB0JIWVvGAYT/FTIniNfNekFElJSp279emrbqxaz7sHuKFemeHz8@rd4yrmcAM5HgtXgdsWXn/3f/zdL/7u5/T3C/r9e/xoQm7x6ftNxhTogfEqFp/eqYe9mfejRByuhNc6gvgad0oWzJdjDZ4rj4WDPscMHbw7c0jivX8lXCDoGglHOVRnL/VJXZwHpXzm4OlUBY2@YGQs6F3MScYjqZc4m/VzK8N7Ya4sYF8DFwh@x17yS9fhH37uK/qgx0v00/lN5xAujOfNfZAd1uBahD/6h8t7xfsi@TjeBHL3WvwNpG8gWAvW6vUdHf@aH/Bv7yP@fRjg30kL/44@4N/JR/w7GuDfoY1/L5v456@ZQHB1dTUYjR6Byugw7WOuU/glEg3nzWPeYCD4W71YAJpDPRq/va0lvh1FSyXnH/SokveGF3dBjuq38fjqt5VotEY5q1WcLK7GMwe5A/a0XuG5pnui8e0qYI@u1lbLxgb9Eo0KXPH6t5Xa6jQGQlKvPH0axQb7FBBU6rVaIHiDdVLG2zKr9UedOpnkKcdrUi5bjyMHXow60J5sBEkJQnIZHZ9Q7kNHXggEUQcucFW4QB7vP3//v@Hv/PP3/7pAnxjCkAByeDi6Fl0TNfFKlC6ly5fGweT/4GAEAepIvDAssSf2pDYIVSYqp@JYHI/EvnEgtcGpwJ/YB6cqdkZiV9RFXZLGoylU9//3D4zBywMDsBkQczASB4hY7MCze3DwEvB1IO0L@FNFURxBJkfiFfyLGop4MqdJz28bkfNAjQnvFVAgElIoIYYSuVBIrWdz5gchFmqc10L1UjBpn58nuWrFUpkSmVG9vW00tvY3G40kMttS9Gk0/hSuciW66jzWgpXS2nkxjnXs1nYwubp2XknH0Z2LQgWm0C/6ldcEIzwri@cBGCueneHv7PrqmrvIga7zM7oaPPjsLMm9rs@c6xqu5NU9CKYcDLTUf6T/9sF/Wf8vT1m4Vo8Ap9/cwsCXrgj@RSI3tze3zr0SCYedl/Aq/KEHvGOcm9sKOgnoBly1cKQeub3lfnAPR1Y5wgomslqhyBNAaM1Bnup5qMQYDKvCzorc@flIFCOlJvh4c/PyJ1rciZRo28tSExfkYCghLUcIJJsplTKOeyVfKuUdt5TLlUrLHpQIL44TgBRbbpWQ0UtBM4J54OwfFnFGhmxVh8KOYfM104RhoVQQP33yvBqNtmo1Guif/vTpHFpSCHe9lAtZ8BHznz5B8wtFYMi4bzjrrQUYAErJ1AR9T7blwcAKf1TN2HkId/zZ56EIhqdEEYExPsuuruYylUouA@5cPhIpCUt8y0y4Gy1IkdulpMCLAYO5UNAJkvIrEfK9DWE4C66ytQqwuI0Xu7kNErVZJhsJN8dKxPOQCgXuwzK5cD5acP7KixGWrCwz569WS0czyyvLT@v1iWaCUqJ0I5el2/KNXMQJhttSyzEUjbuz5SdP0gUgS14snQcajc3qSbWBXzLCxWuUuehJ8iaAC5OmFarRbFC2UK9hQernoVCx9JTXaz7LgqGSAxcPgeRi@QKVNwhDTrWDxzJGgBXxBoJFaTmVXkxmR9/ktkQYKi3jVavV8ql8dBnk2nKhUK/XyXeVx2DLQZNJK@ngcsCkvUYrImvjcq2FU2iL4Al1x5q4sm4rmuYa4L42LK19rbaVxUDwcK@6sXUSS61C15Tarm7EUsen60EJX7OTdwpO4/vRVnXz4BQiHO5tVY@3nu2@3jo9BH801wtX/1BWhkpDuR4Or/G9odC1odryxYVsmg0TrlGHizm8Pv/yJ59/@d99/rOfff6zn3z@s1/86vtf/AR@fwm/n/Hnz/5NIYv3X33/z//i85/@GXj@e/j9O/j99a@@/6Mf8R@9/w38/k@f3984Px8c/wUA1@/96vuf//mvvv/9P4bfv3R@f3z39wd/Pf/3ix/f/8N4P/@Lh2F@9m/h979yXC7sz/6U@@HzDvyfcrjf/@PPf/i/8///6Pyh888@/@Hf4M15@cnPPv/4559//Duff/zTzz/@p6nPf/Q/S6L/9hfAPP/wV7/E/5//1T/8u1/i///yr/7hr/6Hf/i9/4kcf8Id//e//Df8/ve/85O///G/@Pvf@f6e@08evH//CP/v/xF8Hp/Px@B5TLm@1uf7H5Sf34Qak1SAB8hGN0uBKrU@VliJBUQmOjdoI7/4Z5//6HeB9f4QIOHtv4c3@OcvEPRT78ULidJYNR6deP6UsU9J0PHEp588UED5P6IveLNP09jIV3R9f/X9v/hz9J6C/V0/BlG6C7uEwF5qP8W242XMD/tTbH2ff/mjz3/@Tz//8k8@//L3UKLGM4VYNRaXvjDlBYDZR8AhYO4xcAAoreLq/yJbDKTAsbiKUzQBKfr@PZB1EVwwpFgOZNPwFqzXcVBSOa8lK@fJ8wq/6vCeSFbQJ5E8T2J4Igkjkgb7BsZy@Hv6dJl9E4/z58QvIFUINeQxCl2RBAO/ZT7jEsVhPPxGgUwB3nAOJgo9aJQHRSFoPcrK5XI0MCpDGIHCK8YZsUoeZwRwDFkGvBiJx4k18qCUs9E6YYGY5egRayyXRzxiFD0qhIFhhtDrSJBSQjRf3oQEy6NNhrgQeTTwHp7vy5V8eVRBdN9RFgBHdB2SBKgy5m5U@Q7ey4QT4AOjze8gK/lyNFrJg0@ZikqpxRqUppSlwlHZo4zKjf4w0ofH2lPGvhGkvMAHuVAzzIHGe3QCvUZzPWsQfh5ddopD/66TfssYH6p9RPThfjx8Db0pvgMAeONx3HgGP6hGAHgKwSOOKkrJwiPKMQDlos5MjOdB@ks0EKX6jdILpA95eNy1WvG9IDosztLSErhWK0JaOIChELMui/ZAtnBdhlS8IhNyBQG9cR@PsnRIg6XlzWW4S/C/tUh7cTk5lgNLIRwth5ibRjyaNjJGkHLvFo3Kskw5jxJcIDjx5@o5La6BXp1hkUCYPrYRwdK3FNOE50u7u26MQIWOCUJMyvHp84gzJn9rFIvl76TMSgCe9D7E73w4X5yAasBvaiawsSJBKzfxVWq44ARNLBeoVJwFQiYFKsdbJxDh5IBJKTHBQO@@yaykMtlMNpXO5bIrKSmTK2Ry2XwahF5OzKZSUiGTKeQLK7eUpacgOGLF5WZ2tfJP7lz/zT@Zd833xStQecNGCRa/DVRG8XgyRTkuS9mV0rgM@SCvQIXmKvgIY3wTx32hgXPah3aDW54gW4GbOLLpAlwssBBgC@AFF6DFpRHmrNfvHpSchUv8BBRfvBSkLDBCJHAOjMCxBcx5VwAr7wlInCcSd2ZzE6eIzhM8u7kP6UBV6GwPN4oODHZi8A2J60orsOqcOqwEArTaUwPC1gP4mZJaPbCa9ELnY9ro8Y@2blgGqOk/HGZd1i950KbKz5t5QTsyWoGz@@qgdw/EqdnHMz@K9Y@GYavfhAzirC4HWIebpRnGPIAVdnp4TylfemfBcdmUDoMD@NHus50T3/Nkq7qxE8ix9YP9zZlH1gHKsr2t7RPvdYWHulGzHoq3W3t7s6/OA4daiyy7EouBjIQbPmN00TOx9K0LIiXu74u7wMjQRyVX2VKH4YA6C00fRn7lijzqwIhRSSQbCmuU12vBeiWfya7kxMIKe7o/7A@RBqw7zO8eoLQT0itCUVgTpIK0xk6LiyXrZnBbwi@atuSBHMusABONKtJa4CVuqCtI/GCIagd2YCzXx6@RoN2uQQDPsLVxUwWO0Zv4rcahye71hAd6odNSuz2QhNeGCxBoyjKD39deEF/xX4OHPQY8DfK7E6LNAcclRLXDxECC5vZShXw2X0in8rF8AQgs5bLZmJSKSSv5lYIYk0QpL@Xy2YIUy2cK6QzITAjNFlYCQZAtaieZhC5BEgR6qnoLjUCvojVtI9GrBIJ8agT64bAMHX6EBeVgw/Md5pmQzp@LEFnAb7rYA9o3vKyWBfwOuIhf2QbUMmux4Pb2hri9LQjr@IJzmRuiILTxJZsXxZV1QVAoZAMEfEoQDB4HggBswF9EcX1DEIYcAZ5xF4QevmzlULkVBBVfNqrb25jOBb6kMD6AXfIQ/qK5LysApuNLOk3asSB88NABXJUnlKGcbuELpokh2zxkA8IE4ZmbH1EEDEccjmPYcctarQrCLn@pVjHkORU8y7P6Al@qdAmCBS/AjYLQBUfXUhRdEJrgRJ4UhBa4WmMZ/ND0Nh6H1geyIIw5gZBEgjAiaLl1KYDa5fhjMjs7O3Jv0Fa6/Bpb/NmCrEGIOhpubTefPWt2u01rXN16doQhz5/vyBfjodXsNp1ozQZcBsSBkMv@ePaCPO42GrI2N@QFhOgzIY1xQ8G8NeQPkCfn6mIi/cZzCHkOIaM5F8cGVx9Am3it9@G5LjcpxL0ohJ6jZlMoIaMOxqaCk0nYeGj7VawvtyyjhO@j8mIoHIqNa6l6iXxZPxy5EUu3GNgJ0xemUFxGbsa1UVmsgyYulXBOK7zYR9GVFYqL8lp4hO4ciDMplREixcXlUfg81oisCSnQhYv4qS6jE2KhuLQ2zAs5kHvL8ATZhyJwFBZDImNwi0VqK/U1YQWRCmtrcaEm4SvAyPEMpoACc6UgREq3QIoBdFjN4UBpNMLha0W@jEQwt6hZULZxmjxyw7ebjamsaqkTHsVGZZ4dNo6UsDCWMhhChyXewdnGY@BD/LQNx9wFwozWxCKVHjKTx3wkk5FVFE8oUOD53pmt96btz87mOPmVYMU4/w6WlM9FEriVvWF0GvS5EfbeD4nq5BmeOKHTpu7WJNKk7WLgBHVO@jwxQwMTTfzyHJ0FhsEMt3TD@FBeWikEAhVHCcMD4olt/HKlYSXwW3iDkj@En2t2vU6U0SCxo@Ceopbrt8GPeia2RvhlXtXQ3YDjMagV/cTuQeJUt@WOUrqJn8Vv6YgyHhrF4/Jqm8nlCrjkdpjSZnLkmorRqFTKjXJf6ZuDMQxjSJOueHGhE2XrjEPi8RN3Bz70tlA6saSjcRjqfJdGwVGg0sZT8Ovl9ZthsQiwtyWlTF/kFIJCqbOml4eUwUPFwsMiuwfQoSt4KqPVe3@@hXAbQMib23jFYlA6NxO7NieOt/@f8nOD@XECGmXxttQt19D/E95W44JQj8drn@qgX5fF0jgol@1hk39CSWzCACBXGoGftJIpaUAafkJnifbpyaUea5ab345KVtkcWkqJwD9p0C82Eg1oj7VUKhVLiYVYSoLeD3pFCIbfCrxn4CfBD8KllfriYlgLC4wJMXEkJqSYpEixgbGlA1HFYhFpC5VCr/CUI9HUshZuG0xejVMdQWMsYQZAIPSYqcZ6YYh1pMgaB49EP6zl4iyTZZHSByCBtRRuJ9Yja5lSO7zOGhHwgC4cfimWy5T8VRqOlDplFv42UgovRsq28oGPNKiI5iIQk485luxhvyYu5qTYTbwRv9Vke7AkraSKteFSLS5B6cRP3VXhXUWoA6lvAzA88c/cg3ZQAj@3oXJ9YqIRTPzMEmiBmgIVIxVSJQckYDpSA@gXxg9F8n1r4VBoJRUKRUIlgFoEb5I@kRsSESGQYKEnEsgt6KuLQiEF4RNhcycHfFyVkwLB20BbtU2WKQSCN4Hbm9vVik//fMHGYzkad1@fMNaNwiA7SauNiUaQLZIrnqjQDEO1XO0eVUsOdHWDRsNJ3w4Bds5PR8aTi1@7wBldrXzLn@e47g1pgi7aNLQaqzursKl0IGjfBDgJafNAcjVaSZ4HBAGboLNcFc5nI84o/bsg2eplGzfuR3WLL3GoyMJykTeuWj3y3b6q3eTT8Qrfq8eC30HxcVtMJfldEJjp9pbI6mxKCQR1w/cR@wGIMpDe2ayAY3qFmceFb1e@zX/78vTg9GCbPRWL@WKe0@b8aSwmhaTQKg23QYdUj7YCQfMTM7LSd/rzUrBohtKZUNo/PDgvB0fllFcy@kpluIZLffCr12DEXo@AazW1Jq0UQTo7K3Hhoj00FSuyJuVSxc@/@8epUSW1lkpliylRigTtz9//azzknFoJOi4ptxKsB53FvsxKBF5oUSklBStJx5@FpRWMHHfepZVs0C58CqbEfCCYf/n@E2OrMNaotLtdNUWupMsYSzf8Yjd3r2jyrt/t6i38V25rq6u3NONx6zjwdnvLg6f@6TG57oGZhNe/bXzbKH4XX@X/q3Bb3DjgRBZyWYFFgu9BCtk2LpcVgjiZFYJBWoilsnh6MgrCF3qvmseYUum2VDdN81vThCHGsk5/ir2Mf5P3Zdu2V5e9VwUDWbYiMRiSJJOff/ePUqnc//Mf/uA88gpkcKFQyEmp4K/vXsnlhQBbXqiyEDe@xztwNLLrnckLTX32Eqevlhfim8cHGy@2TrAHV3T8HDzbONhPYBB@sXxyqLKlKbKljZ1Plo8RCjv@k41DZljsdPOQ4pzRcVrypVkqJ5Wl3XbR@bhY7IpJiTQu3GaTYiYpZZmUL4orxVSOySARbTSf4biWMCqjYm0Y5pgPJcMbEYq8UEUYDNtTYcRvK0X27HCPYpDIWV7Y3Hp5wA72994mXF/uf7Kze8yOD7ZPzqpHW1COl1vHTKges91jgZ3tnuwcnJ6w6v5bBsFH1f2T3a1jRJAMoDRFFZcTzBvXsVV7bCdR/7VpcDflbRutS2Uw7S9bppxEq9HT3jp@R0rBj7BM@w91FUaO/nHjcXWBa40M0cvtthXAc7xqiy3gSHFhGfQPPEbcE@0Vlh2@@Sha2UXWyuyHVlhL3NfTqytME50/pmX66SO2uLh4rgteV@Qvhjds9XvhCRDwm@Rp993WQjiXYcswRE1lIpOQ/YPDBdF9Wzg7OlmQvLCjzYWU97K7vZD2XrbgLeO9bZ9tLmS9t/Xqi4XcJNr@xsKK97a5tbGQ996ASRcKE5z7mwuSGHCJdQUq4gJ9WDW8vbu3xZYBKFKaCsW5Q3TMeAMhwqDWcaMqSHK2vHzdM2I0@mmOZ6DbypegXfApqAVULGtI13qMLRsm3EBlBWCIFvBGILLVbcUcrGh3DbquwE1gAQu0gAUCePo8PcKxxTJL8S/Hd/gekjC3wxljwqlNh3a/sdkqDg4qwAwxMuRGh7chhuJ8YRm/M89Rhjs0v9qhHekEKkFOBUuIRPDE5/7p3h5PzCR9OCwQJP9cvTAHp2ECNigi3LHo4Msrh1cL1QXSasHRb/Ar0IHbqdoMzNYmkgLKubDQAgTT1L2StRhD/S6G@xYQL77wkyQADMHgFsHFj7qGwy0sa1cZtChDESTm1sE2LyHufCiz6VqOMEyUKEXB/IzKp0/MfTsfTL9a0696iON2kPNscXw8p2WEjaDfgnvGmCDIngLFXECOiUYhNhSHwnzlWgCiw4@bX3BzWYGExBB78oTysQpvhRAlgfGilCKLIwgicAhG5ENkXtYWKbuRheQybj6irUhkKxj7EW7EuTn2TMeAZJ3N6Eyteq3Qq84FHcbNpRmB7AR12ljX4E6nGvCO4hE4Ocaa0ExizA2UchiIY8kYU2KsA94zMrWh6sC5ijWRiS4rQGOk2t/f5DXE7SSRP/egEoPcK1KFgbB4gs2XGH1hoWkp8mXJhQJ5SFDAt8g0YSQEh3s43tEmRVvm7QXZEmM/JubudtHlIx4b2MHhNCIrmrbgvOIUlzwrE6A7@B1k2H7LgJ6zJEcWjToQHpc5YFvTcPE4h7t1@fILhdiaLcXiV5cCxfK9pdh6ZDF@s1JAtzZhESgFiPgw4I0CNN2mazM1DwX0hYSCSvPDUEAHOuElaONTCB4RH7rcSfz418eHTro425Sh3UINcqnAo0y/tqZf29Ov2HzBR2arqyyVYZ9YE11SDlxo4oDlwdHmsnI6Ymf6laaaykxx43Q8CcxTAJ5DUcnBkAHvCmOUIAkbvz0j9/ELaGVW3W7s7m@dTIcivoTdcDLeGxi6RmlEpsGcDGG4HcaXiJejcAeJwPXN8CFPI0b0bByfHG1VX8YgfxG2OmkBszoA3JyWMFWCWzcF8NWVFvTH7RgLH1fZcoQ9wZzFmDNtgS@PTkIzbAVQ3Ztie2imKCmRg3jv0y0piC0yMCcpIczCEfbp/By6VHGFSX3zU7qf1lfSbTZOr6Cyy/F4Oogj5V0Bs8@bJlc2ELLNbY4W5yZ2IYosY6XZQOmBxj0Srbv4qVy32LdRt@gexDYNGpTZJYbn3lG2OGZroF@cVm0e1iKpb0Q@QF9sxuCH3TlNT0ZJP0f2pFBXweJ5aStfm5cvabTTeYnzvKxSonfz8GtnSheGS4GZw/Zk/ccwB6aM59GdwAOaCD5ELysQ4FM5PiNwYQO/OjWIFMl4D8qURgONDTcaYVvROsCsxtBqQZeP6rLtgOGFoQkeSA0JHdOBDnlQf5oO4J@nR1Ou0OvMIETzLOCNJifDlGIg4OXMHigm5cqXDZyxwy@y@xOEAfbUO1Qrnuv05ThSdLTibRnbg4usNmW3i@MY2r3YHG8Qz3d9PTadE@axzZwwNM84L4prb2BO2MWwPy8HIBjuCXFODM8J0Y2DeRG42atJQL3mI2DNT@B6PRyZX/XQrqZr3Ge3jOh/Yg0VxwjX7oGPBUG5dDjQV9fBTQWYtqXiZz1mEXk2CyBmeBTxmU/w2Coy4STZbqnqLHoXk4OIzv/SlyvYqNjqAdZvpFQ@EvMh9GFsc9PG9@FkPqSQwzlIguyYeN@dZLU91MiCs3gn8RNo/UNvw/BuEsEwH4DH0AksVr4LvICG27wQj5nnNLkJuuJdxiF/nP7H6pemTNzdB@0WQor4CfqbJh//2uTjvvSxTf6gpMusNp2PetT3XgSPSRndBv6DEnJzPZ1a5KtK7OcaRbm8h33RFJEvGW6CZDpZD40jgTyecotC6NHjkUICcfkRfYV8oepzDCTMiz3pf5bLLC55cbjEm7QGmpf2ZT6AxlMaDbQ63GiQuclGA2eWGg2Bp0AdL3Z4/k7XaWw8LAFaasOg0LAQl4WYEI9Xjzd2d@OqLsT4lxLKgj0wLKWBVuOEGC55lwUSWA2E6SmaWRacLYuyzSi2cH8aVV8aUMAvJ0JAPJVdnRKZmBP@cnItf5GMRxTJmElsYuL0EakdUWpozeGhlCxuK9BNaIPM2aF9QEtRUdDwb0AgPxgdsvsyZW4Ep/SdLPB0bZrps9HIC88SPRro59Q1WkvZU2lUTbN9gmv@SLhjrchp7TjVgwgmnMq5Tzikb8IxMoXXVhw9i6aHEsLEDKqTsYRTUh@/uwoatx4z6dCmTSI5@Y25c5M2TmPOZHUiWAwTC18T0GISVMChYcLds5oEbs9uErjRchJ6uaIO3Gg2CWN0HIdjQQlcZEMJnsDewsRka18eqf0hTtz47XI4mtwkW9jlY0mo16fAaenHKYoQCQ1tX4cdvJGoUBSg6DbZa5q12YTw88w2ReqBu0KWjIxjNn2qwzykcw1BRWK/hUryKWIomm0nNxA3JjCBKyEUVyrWYfDp4x1XxKD6PONn8FlPRAQliXnxJ/2Vz@xTeWp4gRSBwQPPzCQCn2Xyf4aVlPtI0VNBJjXmh@KK25x8427jezPux@AqapHAAyOp/9@Mk/xV8l/oUOn/@0HRnaHPP/JQ5oEhzFePVn6Lw4L/qtD/V4X@Byj0vzVt/h6VfBbl3RY/o65/UQ3/evWLZN4Yug2re4VTb6kfoof9lhSBla/SA9xc16SHdIEv988umpS/W/@BvXTg18mTdu5s26hWqyd9yTp6Vu1We9UjtLC1Lu5Fzy4y65vX68/W29XNze7z7sa@8ipfzeyZL97k3z7rfPyggPa@c/D83UfNbPUCb47M6zPl8Dqt5O3qcPhhd2c82Fk/7W8cZ9@uXItbWrazrnzY1OzNlydvXpw8yx5Hrz88P3z@sS/27cOOKBf66Z2Xudcb4zM9kL1ST9vbe@pB/7i9dZrq722qb7ejG@LeceGVJO5tXb9Lb1xHs2Jy13xx8Ozo9KK59U472t172974YMi5D5fX5m6yXehsXBy9DhykX0k7Hw4OulupwrOd5PVmx2yLqR3Nyl68OTpcP32703shb/W3s6eFNxfjw1zv1aurwX60mznLDV/amaheffUq9UJ/dnW1dRRoysaJlVbOjFeSeX19aBT6K8qL/Z1u/5Ul6cmD7Ovocf/kenNrXfuwMkqfvj17dZ05fjt8@er5uwNRPT5ubsk5s9lOHV@cZAKtfno3enW6dZqXn7XPXvWvdneybzeTL3vKfrV9qF0@6@68M44P93araXuoS3sbV9rbZ72Ll5ebG7uacXip6dVMMqudtN8eHAROn6vNTWXnjf28etF7m8yuX2beRtvms5OLj73L5@vHpwf51OhwLBob9lFzpzPaPMql8smW9uHoY8d4KZ2@iuauLp6n1LfVj4NA@uM4W9jT3ip9/Xm01X03@qAlo6eStPFu9@Pbt8c7V1azqp9@eL19dGG9bOsH9oF49PzFy6Z2mR9cmO/042OpJT5TLl9GRTkwOt2xoY6UEzm7ctLfe2WONo0PR7vv7NzH6NXZZVrZvDx6Xf1wJDavdfONbu2p/Q2xfSBXXxuDreHoWatwdXq5o@19OLDfBl5uSdnsttGx1zuvM4U3yWfRzuWzN@vS8Ujc1486mZy1//rVmapu9d6cfjxqZbdfm/n@QO@@@nja34pu7Y16H5W82NSO317qgdPs8dFh6lp/ofYH2ztHL3ODA3Hv9WF7ZyxVXynStb6yMc5ujqxc@mzzjfX2ckc3k2/VD8NDUbmKtt@ag8wrtdlpvVZb/ReB4@e90/3D19e72Zz1rK@r64d5cX9vZ2O/2868GO@@HG7tNS/az3bfKG/Mk9xlamv9LLf55jg9OLl8MSi0rvrpw3z0ROsPuqfRwPNhb7hyeGZ9eD16l6n2m0r6SHtrjFek/sZzMzV6Xd06@Ni9PDSNfWk7NU6e7hmXmvjx5Prjjp2rjqP50emgbwxOpFFWehVIX380B8/N56@OD9afH7x7LmdU9Uy@OH7dFtOn@aTas9K7udwzaWu70//QLyjSx82XaTnd70Xtvctke6N9@vrsUrvov@hftAL5gt1a3303lI2tZkoS3653trLK3vreiaScdl8cZzb3xcM37cPTD6OT9sab4enrA1Xcunhe2Otm3hy9LrxYeXdin8hnxpsX1n5glE8btpQrZK/Tx4X8Qc86Tp9dFAbvXlzk1rWzpvR8N9VXtlXrTX6cvzQ/9q6718eK2Ow@2/wgH3W2QJKeHopydni5PzoOpF@f9K9WzPXo28vWize6pOXP1JXkyYeLwmWv9@J6s5U5q378IGefXSiF4@1kU9vOPosebbw6vOhunn3MZ9ri@t5r@c1oqzd4G3i1o25eFM4uD0Zj6dX28bhfFXUte3V8lr06MdaPz3aO872XTavT3LnogWzoj08vrodXO8pKb3Sdf9G7eC2Le2/yG7qdORQDz5Xdfvvo5MWbarSTUgqDq4O3@@ZZ/myUfZk3zgrGQV59Ue08G7066GyJK6Z6djI63eol1zfUfh5kyqF2am0cvNp5d/bcFAMpPbf@ccPIrnyIXo3e5s6Sh9G94dvWSap/Zlk7b1Rr@83V4ZsXx9Xd6G5z/OzwUj54u5U93t/YsJ9Ht9WcMt5JX9vVjbTWMQJ2f320P7LMQvrd5V4XegKjXWg/O0mf6Xa12rnezR9vVavP7Obuc3k0etZZgT4Cr62z10Y58GtuPTHADSfyh8wNsAT6drdpjEBe8tOPATq5FqCTawF@Vo02a/Mtzr9OLgdO/Ec08ICeY9J@2ARljbUNVB4SbNczcYxfOImxvgHRVXS1DJOeiNY5jNLGAZ8Gd5qvwvOV9DVUZWRqhoofj8IPWeCY1Jp8uDARONBZf4zjzYHS5wdHVPz@k2ORmL59wT@zRRZRAwutFnO/GZsge7veF2TfgwJh6t04GVjusni81dHkrg0OrU2u94Fj7wMAmIKmyjj5gUlIew1ZErPO1lT6ziNm7gQ/W7X/jOFH9HAbrDvikEGZGJNdGpykIts0Cn5X0lavFG1Mn0pR2okA3/H5qF2Qfj/cPz7tR1ZhZ/aGgrqhWDMbQE0e0V1pTS4/RdtAT5eTzhIrKkMN2WqqA/xqeYOf32jwFN09b@b03kM6/Ows0HLFCDUbsqfMnX15hG8zsZBitId9cvwQ99NBiqCiursNl5dNQkn7rhh/8WFeNu/Hrfa7vy3UU7jbqjKF1wBaDYFWtCB9Z83@G5s2OXpApQBfrN96s3vScL6nw7cYTp35umfHpY/KJffNLPES@PLv5PzutkzcYQDZx2lHbo4cinplcF4WaN8jbo@E2sYR9mS3ZQK4hnYaIDaTdqPUMnW@g1CkrXsuwb04TzgnPPHl6smEoAvOhgqPBx4Zj2/Q5CB3y4uIO5aiEADt5nQPqcxs9vst8949NdPUZP0SXSW@VRbGC1bLV1n0pRBfOXAqyyuLs3@Sn/aDckNUbxvsJKOC5VULATgbYt1qPtWxOdN@e4zDa9hLGufHMA1v1KVpRis8CV52t9zwskXclDj8TFIHOJPYwZ21hjXmCeH0TLhUAhDcp0MyQdHd3aq@Upcn1EB0tKnHlwvg25LrhZYWlEk@Y@zh3PKkFokdaAfQ/KzyzUAIVfOyVedJ3S8Lgd4Rf2Gmok6I424hAmdymQ0ME4jQcTgOujHiEb479Q5V@E4vj4sYp1NNrMM/W/O/FPnGXWxQeKafoQiJYDPGEfpM5rxMI2jFazqY1IT1qKJwBzdWoUq8yFQY4aM/U6PRqXryIa@pSDeJRYna4TmhIIa8Ejmkd2hPMLQnDmqDb8VlHb6Di9M6MEOiVUjo0yevwcCrx42H7slSYAl@ctRgNjI450zelh2Cltx3txF6bgqZEMWTqrd399LTsVoYgBvXpjpStDAIzAZ@J8hk4OVsWTJN7iAIb/sSeGNlU94debW4GIZYNYJL5uvsCQtLq6vhlXiYvL7JRyJeY3Sip3zRfZFBSFcqLJxaDqfdyBmMDCjT0wgy8xGkOILMclhyEaQcBFIWMHAVg5B8w/Kca6cR532IPbz1aRj82tCc1JdTUam@uprHPZ4@z5nIqflZX05HUxCZo16ITodwtDzA51@fLhEgT6d8/YgPRSaaBhQ86eh0wCTVmQAvUX@amfrczum3pry45zTczoei40dPFauWx/Iip/JN6SYDtzmwHE/88JxJn5@b@HGWXkY2Bx2BmiSk1lPw0FSMf37Q6bSAfqWZXtF3OIIgUAwQEVw8aoxdPNTXNb@@s0PgDk3w8TLHmBRjeRiGgEQBiZGHyCBCiAZqt9Hqmx4cdMX5CN/xzTswSmQfV5zx/ADUE6r9bkokxjj5cIUb8Dmff6M@hNM3DBEae7vr@Hi9dYQ7Znf3n0EVLmA5Ymxyd4u5yDF6RdyQdf5JGnWgQhZAtvEBjVNWXlXT6aOnm76DzUXuwM9i5xGpdAjBeGRHOyS@UAcN1XCwcVK6fKQMiI70hTQPIB8pwTiDXStM1pAcY/5l5zz/kBodeqPYRCpweBGdDCKFkGYnR9X94@2Do5dEucNGde9wp4qYYYDZkq02o0/9YAPRdUXjnapHzwB2vyCheZnkpvtdGhUtcRAs/2YkJx4ANiikQb6zOcLycqa/A8@950UgieJBg1LRaCvmHNy4d9UDcwpjz0HIa5Hn2ukKnTzN6wmpw7vbE7pytIKSjmhpKLYeGgBj06ePZJ3Lk6SLbx1GmfTdSGq5qEd1iV8s/qG8dIq@no18ZA9NXB1W2oKf/HKrpdhkymFCfUCpaB1KxJEsPkKBz/zST@QHP5vi9b0ODvp4KHW6oqf3TtTcaWURtEdOux@k4/oUJI7F1ZFuXLWS1CInZf4x7ynVUZ1WGe9LjKd2wVO7gNS4wGUXswqZWq9dTCli88ijuuS54Lqxq5lx9cTbSk4114FGb/fQ5BLNhXCpQxWG1UT2RYzxlKx74lbZE7cVT1rifOXuYaXMIey0RuZ0OJP@0xkwt9tAtvCduQ06uUKjr6GF9c9fdOUaX6in5Aed3CEGwROnNECdduFc8YlnqO7lDMQE0pBOy9Sc5OrUqXj4wg5CFnfzE/HpGnQK05kVUHWQFpPDaU5ZSZU0bGeg6PNEser0wlbbbeQEOenMrPbsgS4EQl9@4HByKoEf4@MJ5dFJHx4tE2rkkInOSgFcV43HIUKEz2uQTgPiFstA2VMH84uRv1sMp3CuTqbyEzAo6hy3xEUBgn6CcQ/4uomX5pbbVw73MBxGjvgKJpacExTuid7TQ5aW0mnf8d@Ds32Wy01OB6NBN5ZJiZMjx2jajeUKgR80TzaZT@D8iA3HqVBkK@QZHLqDLqhoGjRi/mir2PVj3viweMQf45KnXC3zEaztiGOna7BZf2jjFCWTcYSORyulkZQILIBQpDlg55uobucNgN2hbMn6QOFnLFGQOyu7mCBFRB1WsaBcTWgZuG0MJX4fDevZQ0vhE8Dg0zZatEkScVA8qOlhn3YjxVBhuFIsNAOgDpyD/gskcxx24KKhwpnA9XSFQ8XlDU5CRyRQi8ZJFk5G6paRenzqxXGlSF052RMplyd7EnVp7ueVMQNEXodViMbcHVhwCHynm6Hx@LLzjTm3SXrAE9E/b2rwbifDB6fuONxBw/uYuyN/tT5nMoa4q@Xvg0bOJiZCRWWqR9wzcCQB3CNQLXceggPRY1Sn7olw8dEoUhDGL22Vz4UzkhGkRVAvRV2KhVyHu3QcS34UvOB9YJ74uQytL@LsDBg7B@a845EOBLJ8hEM4ZyNnIbB9coiRHwfkgjfU5eRk/8EIcXjn3VB8E4e4o3B0R5xxASLg41pSu3j@@Zm0@aVw2iglyo@kzeaUgiK@tjwfjBfZAcPS@cAgUySPlj3jOBzs9HBy7s0FpNzThNRDmZ9K7bGZd5K7AzRFiUdm3SPErTNXNw8pRO4bVwpfpHK21Thqpq9@uJIElegwAvEstXtnqsKhgSsVeO6avhhcZ3bjuJKEQpxDv3dFjgPlOZZT7nFgV6B705yTc73zCso52S2qW0yqQfrIu6aa1DVOl9VpFv6yxqW7hV3xFdY9ZTxVWCeSW8679h10cHQ045rbX8AORXBOLgvftGPsmzYuhjg@/j7KpcY8@Td91tnXIL8tT1qkVz4vr3Ro1nvhbdVZO0TR7ud3jId4RbeR41e@qQuQENzQS@7meh5rYcFRZ0DpmYqXijjTzh47uyg6HZDXtFUfTfjupVxME44hLGX2HcdDXdBHxZoCdsE@kZzHDEQ82I4KJfXB@rjIkcxTjdTlDgyIRp3@rDw1Gzw5QH0vI/qxOLLTd0T5wfgkU@7mYoxhvJucj8ON4nT3k/Zf8mdkfG9GkBy0RuT0dd6aETeJcPubroxOdDfT0dxA7zJTcPvgKGKO/pYVXT0gbE70BW90wMcDft3AUbRdZRAntkCBh7ExPxodY5D6vfATCyMf@AIfHs2DmGQBxB@NTE34BRLPYco3LDJ9g5i72aTaIYqavE6m800VSRMhHnZejCdmDZElU3FcBuTOqHSnVFPoGB1yptm4Ejf@QaosmmCncarf@gdW/DIWHpcsJ@MsEw8Hu7sdCIXaNzWFn9yR9hrVg13PtBXrDQZmMZlUbAO97IRhdZPX6qWa5ICBY8dsVVwZYjtHI1U8pLF1Cl0ZGpwaJNixwjcroN6Latl7Gk4qw8h7jIQWsHQA7nRA49VbCn7YZnCN@wccBHbCn1kIlm3Qww2djQ2jOcm97JzM4RmIUd5tyHwXCDNsJiADyZY8sJWxksSIyaYGt76MhrSTMCRPYgmTB7qyB7GPoUkoiQv5Sg5s@jJGJ6dnUiVLd4E4zh1RyAC/Ck@7R3AOYYD7IlnTgLrx9qc6gwQyhWno2pjpaAKgC5iuEBqkCiSFnHcNxaQdt86iDm15UGgckRELORL2ttPDUTzsvxMJCMtGAvyLxkU832EbyC6WQntTKfrUnpaZPRm8YU5vouDj/Gm/Fhrn@vI@DW@LRzLpi2voj9n3MW@PB9n/ArLft/MjmcTpUVOTx0y4lsmEOdvIrIi5Io611K5ObIitBY3o@DR2ZYQGvG3cGID9uBtXU64UjaWxGl@r9hAAjwdDKFIgaFpyty@7gOF0kWEyPhtdNL6eOtE/CTIMbdqng@cm2GREjSfTGJMm2OgEl9OrIDEdb6dfUCIgteC2hlueDcNkRXC0leawS50BnstyY@DpKDnWxAhypBJuRtbgWYQnZJ1sYkM7xsZf9uxX4X4iQ2U1aOZ15i5QCKUAlQKafpnnvuTGx54DwXwrOtBh81UN6BGWWcMZjPJZAoDGPizM4Ww@70mL5y5I29g9wFkbSpBvLnZDsIjcmGCkdO@ekmXm21MCIgHtTSFjkgmsZNKdGQlV8QvP7st6iIfSrFGYuydTRLzXW/bI4e5f6PDdJ6tkE4yROVEiZ6Tk7qqXSuzWBcQ9IKjh4M6SeMjdOYAapoVrM5MdKUB6wR2FPYTWl4H0FyCp4pDNsF/yFYNv8K7z2S5HBZkNluruGhb4l8WSSw3@QXiv/ieLWU94bS5QwRfp8/I3zFGnhRZfiKFVEmeBaSqv2Hk5PELcwXE5XXyY8wN5THODM5tIk6Yxb0KVZ5TPuYKwQJ0zTl1KjI1YF2ff@fApxsbOK1rjD3CT22JsXJZKnl1uRR/2b3AwEuNRhmYMgW@ZAtK@FMC7M6KzeOJe64ZegsQ6CvIACQr0qrn@OLVxI8aYdFuilFv0mTcu4kGPuMv7c/dineuIr1iDoQj913k3UfymLcR4erhkQA7JdaTqsUlqnIherkdj4zI8io1BdDA8j1RxRh3odibn6XXsC/p/2/u25jaSLL1n4VekoO4GINypS5OEirqRPa21JMoUNT0TFBuDS4GsFojCoAARaIoTXt8ddjhiveNZ73gv4cusHfar7dj1RtgPfu/5D/sL9h@Mz3dOZlZWoUBS3T09YUdrYpqozJMn75nnnDwX9lGi32n0AQM5bLuDd8c2xq5oPJCp9twjBqm98CDDE/9fIHhlW7ADGcBvKgKsVgFIHKoyxC7n8zDT0Tcvl5FPTF0yfzbeBJdtyi/lY/YYv5R38Z/HTvJ4HNrzSntRMnopVKK9uMlDYNVTzpe6y837Bv1dam@qv0vjYfu7Yjxsf5fH82v110qMf8QdoSuG/4DHAct@nzhqgraJIqe4r5DYiG@o7R@nS8/GiLmUKs1RMpZLh@NxGME5e3YLpM6MRnC@k0513pc6Nuk3Mch1ER811xu09RDvIMrJFp@EoBeL/BtxOeX@InpyKLJtfUdzAjBvsETfflZT31RBSV8lbpI5Em3/UJWcqUJOENn2hvWLPeVU1bIN544KD6a4sO19Scmng8PpOqsvUmtMEQxUSWUVmYHuQLl0EaRlF9Gjrs/HZCmMusosZSYRpbV2paGE@NjJPxEuKaa6885bU5tPZ1quDj1h@Vgr752XzQKXyWBJb6FsbmlixZ4MWNr2WBSx1QstnYLZE5Hw0@NJODs6VnAUBRoQsKJSPghB3YO6JKoewVhn8FWzadTiinH3rfy4rl6NFTH5bD@PnfvshXoMwr@7gCxZZAFF55rQGlbXrhna6Vos0r7GJ70FPhRBn0gc4up5zpwGbGM9UBOeQRJH1e/xcsqo2Fxi1aalQPKd6RSRAUBZB9IFdD8uNsYzTFwQFIDx8cXEyjULmt1YWcZOa7l1bnOf0lLJam0js5FshppuZNeHqK9xQeNEipiW3VBzUDtas@3/FubP1iqv18T3X7I0qVKzKisM5xOTC@VoInZgmncCz@bwrCErlThwQvk8nIA3XFQyMZ9CHse7q3NKvBezyoAr13RzjomffQtFo8zS/OJ23KGpYtMBIKIWMGklb2d4L0N8O5R@xuyoLSwMcMSkHPzOSjPCHl6ZTeHlkZiEPd/vRyBZO1gr3M4izBv0djWvhP2gcwQOkTh1c/Sa5rA8mrnF46AnVhmPX6ApE/@ns2AizDZaU6O5ZL0fWgqPj/3eG4ZFAKcYezUYVWnYRtNqOFDRT2edCUQO4USVC1FOn/Fy0@xpTZw0HaUPqFYCmFeet0yEOMAgP@EKMrWsjLwOohpz5rGyDuKJFCIdzUPLjDC2ruwHUpOaovPKCmToeh5qC90gYjwO@11Rg9kQZ3E4riEPJ2Gys@4XCMvudU@cGCa66XwkgORgTeY6GLUaysRiKPI1rm9iOWkuB99YgkZVK4CrAm15LGd87aDRUCbGLfG8w0ZBsfyCsll@XsR6iwzMALoWE1@zECjTKFW4kmW0fBUvYx2Fo6qLWcCWERMcwEpXnT/vO5o/BQJohLOHDhiYv0PC2OtAWMlN19wn7XTuJRay7gqdAyez4bQz8sNZNFz8thdC7hqHLdW0MyUt@PPH@jNJjoMNE@6sjmAA6kl9l9XdoJsARp0O77Wnm8jJ7@ujBhN3Eup7Vg21GUxUMVGH8ExU3EfeU52Hy9HoBKRy4DIBkh6oCUzZxqsiagN0dLK52Gha43JGwa7Tm874ED0OoVwBndIZ5EHQ8ZjARIynBAc2@gLk4difSGW02hbhTJn7mdZr7OqTDsjY12ZAleqrj/HjbEa3sO7lIiE8wO2ggsrhke@UoeOXGk7gLDuidpvrretrGQUuN3ndQlBS1MDV0l/gDsQGLq7wa9cmr3CQ@aJK4E6Va8CtAG02R0omevbF65q/LxlGP6X/xCSzkXUZWFlQWrcfLwmsVbEsljMMbNBiRYti4EFT4x4sLGhfEuhBcHjdw1uLaG2w7AyzeEoLxO9MesfUJZqvAAtmOuFx6gd9Hjbi4SD2tq7MI0XoEVepJAT0aHbShUuaAY@XNdPkdw8IyQmkGKMucc2x6WXAJ1xQpvX8GqqeLD/ul@zekqqYLwHzQ4BWjoQbVLeJ5Zd6YPAdazbZ0RkU9SdEIWsYFnwf6ES4KdH@6Jey1g6N53rL8q210hibF2AsxcKzlEkYBF5TR8XpNJy8kZcjiN345J92ApZ74y1QFJZRyEj08MgfxXnykmGEc3FYE97PuFiOO9PLhbxmNU3pUByKQY8YTsUDLG94rVhp2WojN2Rt0RHWEwlUXWdBM0rKysulHOx28Zg3V5Ehim1QwzXd0mPtuVtB5lqLMsWubTIcaOoqsTY0pF4RgDYth/hdiyRNHVVGw1DSeOFxuPFlz4C1tLlT1U05B/sv7TTDp9eKP9pqmN0o68PzZHXEdVgl4Z6jqnvTmDeIPlli@DmAsGcDOHy9ceMTQ8SpLTXX@l1saTUXDa9rKf5bSY8PQJJeu7Z4n9HhsbBq4rFMPs@rWW8D5jusMuCarI0Ul2cOxoFs/QxTFa3kKeEO6HpXCKagzTfo0xWGR9OSfa7XGzSa1qIprx3npq/K6UPrO2vfdYZRqF2Z8cUqhSJ@L3y/lxizA6V6ve@6swGagpd@KhMbqCxbp1wf2COHVXPlwV9GisFZ73AGHLL/S462oHGoL1YrBMUmK/qFXxc8MDJxoNdq1AMtI5MeqJttXa3ug3FhhE7wg7fjzoa5qh9M/CP6sxegRf2oAHrJvnzXctsiTHyx@@T5/s5ee2/nhzt7L3e4JCvyW4Pi2bjOkrLoFM69RxpvIUo4xMl9NgnoHseNw3GWwIG/7IXTqfqE2F2f2PE3HSrZmfm5lW/ua09X572K/MmmlN8XYp6N71nTOApgIjSDqhL171QYcHkeLkYlWfx0B7JDKmi9DuHJQOJC5XBm0mEuOTg/sZO6IcdKZAht2YArJRxMT0EBam4i@cZMN82wT7vZr2kdWwMNkUPsL8E6RAABQPnQul3UOFi7u1dp4H2iOUFGoq0SX5l478cN9UKq3eZq1bb0CzRkZxiOjnLae4LTAqbc6NKqIBT8phliNgqiKqC3AE@BGGnpkXSoDv6g3qw16t@eS4P4Eft35K3ga5jkf00772U7/cz4SVlm@yYGgEPjnKds6BJhkzIt6LKjNSUN6lIVremKvp45@Wprco3@1u/YgnyFAblu3e3vxmj827XnvrKZ9Tf2sfDdm@FkLuCEVY5ZvpkqpuffnsHO/ytWI@9nLnKZFcX3phPZphM6oNr7GE8UbhZY@xiUx5NdEdhD1GTFP5HR7tbhjFI0mTm1Eoq2NoJNUmk@jkejNZGvpkSf0KBPqJX/1tThV/c1wxYg7m622vF79Noxjkh0tPFemvA2UM8lKu6utv55ov2mXldtHyrtkwVoz1iQhj2nm5tUkebT5t07lVADF0sX0fHl5a81zK15i3Eq7wjjjDK6vjuMzExKptTfRSiYUdoGeZvqGFkSXisZYk6vVtcmUcM1WgmFeM1HlQyu8@XxS6mtxyMYC0vZiZgrxNdtLd7E2CAQFd8NsD0opecogTIWxq5CmZwaMxerKtMbbckmxL7A//9ibWWXoBh4fG9k9Ts0svreauR7q5HvrUYushq5cb0@iyb1bjCqE2k2VNVTov5zN2hDbe@qzz59uK/2P91Rn7x6/HfUj3dfqc8ePqeUXfXi1aOnTx4r@v/O85c7igvYfz/0J1C5VzT1237PZ@n8WqNxWzHmpQDlt9XLzon6NOz5b2nx3Is6Jw@O5aM28qdbUmrnrT9ZhPIcNIYyy1RbTbCsSN6ajMQJFtddWskneEc0vjzRRvbmGYlkiW0vOBy6NeCWtz2mQViPi5@VrNEGwYeUSmg68iTLutN4WmeipV9TeuDsv/ceQSIKn71UD59vI9Ln9pP9J7vPX6pPdvfo88WP4WZHbT@B25hHr5DFgM92t5988uTxQ06QBjRqCrI1Nli/qAk1gPOo9N4MZggPNgRXqL8SXr1v5HKj0FhFRKowG8Xue/q0pPDuLs5OW@yivfjBw70f/BBUjf9Tlc8jyKXjUF1bIHzQgNEI1aajaLfEmTpIy2pTDqSThfoA2a0cy4D4d0UZ5CV@Jw58lX8MMSIepDluthBsBjVVdJ1wA5VxBOspjsBQKFTuMcotqo2lB6Y2CFYH5gNFH2jHrOAjbxgvrREjRXDGJ6OehNE1CbTuRaubq51OBAACIZ0gAJDBIGHaeeM/gZBE3dEQsykYf0q4KwlfnIw/OQXVCANXnfBIAoGs6zbJvPGUIsBRJxjJPCbMmuR04BgpXCRieDjJGQ6NyJVV4oj@129seJUlyDydggPa2YapiJ/daDXQ2X7cGUwjVfRKkAYTC@KPAtHUOhp2iN1jufAEBktvoUbA1a57@LdlHNUbgpMDcRoWprtQyXbYctv64vevWo5KPlqqEXp73GkoTOn4T5c24NFSA74OGkJUdc8LuBUaT5mwZTThQC/lYhTSiiSWT/0sGdUo7M96fqKA5nWKXwRfflnSg1yJizgqPtw6q2GHUA94CDmFDyp2c0FMDGtKHuM1SuawmOxB/DZ8AmWICRr4EzO4ujaXeTA1ak0cXSno@RW1djtsDHdprbziRTfYHl9j6zOKn78jMcvjZ5Iu2GTLzUXw5wwlBnh2msDNy0BBsWgx5ZZIcIdcfHb8TEX1g8/Xva3tR6@rP/tJ5bBeP5JjodOXxwtRSpRnFmbJaXtY3UnWBjQ7TSPNRbMuSht9RjktscsNMiJcjgMivh@0WzZPxKrL6SOOl5VM58R37zwpVWV7E15CiCQTn24VdWCqrHCZQ1XSCOKzkxoLz7ompcI47Xn9AHHtMQstGpERzhFWr3HDqrF@jePtGg96dLLkNJ0m023xl0wscr2i@F/RnY/658VHXnmrVDdQvJnscBbNEV0xmJsl3atzTC/fV0voti9GR@f31dGtX9g6uR7eC9v2hdjeq23V8mpcci05uK6O9mcXoJXL7Wuhpb5XViOWS3IZm13pdnFWPrhh1vwlNf5kae547xEa3L2IqGqROrXNRkN4iCuKUJyaxgVKLpqYIHq5v72zt6fyO5CybVJZOvc6ox7bl@IYBO7rxtOR2CHzYVezRJMNE2SJJ5NyLualyWov2syZg7fiqNA0SEWPhz0sbNRe4kzm2jpCbhYmIWB4LQeiGblk687MGRQdaMTnB9CEUvGkOR3MZXbzhlw@4mSfD5l43CpCG0dvgrElZvy5dtbFourJwkVkCGFcB50jvHxnz99nQh9vmnqEwPJ/OuMOQwm/B3/56iVVPMZLcS05gxdMi5lS1lnhVXrDjB2b5SUp7G@@oGws9nNNCzvHuiaOddOEPv7AiWTH9OkDvPMvdGbvRMs7zRHPKffcCS3Fl14xeQURkUlssHrgrgoqfniurzAeDXtPepYgd/faB9yaA9NKjmamcbdWA31IFPydu@njIV0VnbYXVlX9dqqSWyJRkxN3a7kGk0mY7965c@sy3OlemOLVb4pb7pD0@Tk9Gb/tOCijRcSqQrRynzyvmPx4AVwwdB5xgf2i2TCpgkTqZNwpib7zZeS2j9pyOoEtHjVm99V@BfKidK0lNU@1LRu73EgudgZZ6oOzhW1HZdcsjf75xdU94qBul9R3/f3rk80GIMjDz38jYTL3wjGOSiLEJ23xikos@WYErbgpSkjwQevp14mB@cDEsTyQeHMP5IUbNtJS44Np@AZ6/SZypo5tlsczVO2kMz57BwHXOxaZSh5sAnTZoKIefCE6KhJZ80E/ZCWCgQ1l@UBamUyjY/5t2w2@uQn1Qc4TAOcB07MDWPiooIjv2YRUwYSaLJQljegTm1SVJFqrU/AeNv2mpMMuIRgPFza9Lul9H4HnbOo9jeW0YyNeFrY0ZDpCZiGvgVlWGwwWbR52m31fsomMsUkf6sYQbzkMbep1SYVOlUk60GVncdKhJBEnZZNuaChcTMHUXUuR779p8yTraHOEsFBRo2B4WNP6U/eLmncsaROOqUwklfdH/RxPCsc8tajMlfAArmX1Ejp4EBzWWIFSH0DgyeKJlY30IIgLuMCU7oS@lEUlxbgB@K9uhG6qu3hR88GDL7DCJ37Um/lqZw4e38RGNKuSHYPcUDvPt9XuJ2pv98VOEjVa3AaNwqWMwh6HYtYN4@6YLVuhCQ9n0@O2JJrPdO6pL7kGhXxboFE4cYDkM51rKmAUh9iW6uxd/506oMt7bCel2C8d6kk3PbZ9qPXC2Wh69m7@jqd3TpRejZbAfXVeg5Dg/tKw6J2oKWyzHPgtDmEhQVe2jVuFuBZO4Vrm2jdHqC2uU3u@dK6x5ez5SVNHO5MP6TggJx2TOAlCkDybOr4lDUfvOA64yW/ZnioW0w3DpVSrLSWX1cc2cKPvRtxNVnbFSsqrKtmIK5EVZvHUIsQRjWsrqX6o3gXvTGXxpYKrfz3N7djRhu9mPY3OFcPbLgHTOHSy5VXC6XM/l/y1tOH0DKpkvFH9uiEbAkHe49PckzWeAOP1vQRmDwcDJhtoCY53QQJQtskSIJdfxtjObmW89TKKZLc43o/LzVlRS4wuo0h2LXGjk1MR7/XUbPRCos4kIAl@tIkRdO7XzJmjZbNU8arNqtIF9VJkdqYtdRblTymjDnNMCwStx0Pzs3kopjeq4Ba7ED45Im4LdOedAcEZxO5UcK256c10unslqS2neBrCaVQKmHCmbqrL50I8iSSSTmGpJduKjbZ0NHDQWvpqpCPn0AHlJbQCtJoElV0TwxIoQJiKw83igMpOTIKWs0Gdxc/wLtZUW53daEHL2aDO/ljCWs3CmgQtp0GXzjU@KJNjbwnam8WLJ6@0go510TlV@XO/N5vKTWOcVtAemtL2cAktDd0PjoLpfRUTWvyrRu3Bor29rj1imzRi8O98bEkfLmBIbbcJutoYIU4Lh5YKMioWcZRLvsWEuSUeE/AS4hrv4w7oAUO406DEA5NuiCEyNENjbjFDirlDI6XmU9ViYySVVzfO6PMc1O/BjTNhdyTye76SL53npVmtxClKfTLJmj@6d8@MRW0atgOV@a@lG884wrFK4qjFSRf8S@CYTW0qRByVYdgTYWcFuFqGWTugdDDg/LCTwoHXlOW@mIKE5vDyduBBZRkHmlBWF3XKxWGYqmUcN6@MwzBsyziqV28H81NZffnwyjiEEczCUb8yDqzA5THN3zgjBOfy33zWUkuMB8yidGqn0k0uDYuzk/jqpvtiWFUFe0HGkICfp76y2qEJc3etDx026ErjAaZjeTyKgeykLbqK@eRuiIC5iZKlpf0izC2nigTW2Xkt9UE07dNFUBsM7f7O2PwpFj0lJNEIWe4BJqbWO54Qi4TZrGnuwxAgjJPa325DNavdZsnQi73dH@w9fNZ@/vAZmKgbckZBfANtGVbXadTWEM9epC1t1inyFFQt0I0cn8NOHrdPo9nhW4Qjx6LUjTMH7jwvBBRq8lheVBv5p@oTyuKg9Us4AVmzshmaniK3wR7q@erbfCmGdG8w0yvNr21RSxhG1oluCcM4yTmH2ZLyr0eiofJ69HoqgF11IDaZ0aHb3tcwXHIKKlV9@3r6Q3/ShS5J1TotlVmECj54N3ZOBZULLUGPMTgT@Jt6XT0yTnG1/Vpn2IPL29mAHd@eBMPOSbffqY2Px7lB5Gn3NMXCIIKTyxyUqZ7s7@y9bL9AnK6dx2w5gX8tztt/8mxn99U@cl5S1i2dvLO3t7vXZgX1vVcv9uExNJWUdwE1lhhMJySAnu9@@vCpAyPfed1IMQiJiN@kP9qVT0UF4/ac/7tgM4@KqEK0OQgPm6mgKKdV1DQ48cOZCd4G/xPmgq/A8gSPMlSXiWrMDmmKEH/qvNjX6bkDxe2YzMZTBmUN@GJqJErJEgJzEh2hAPsiiohuZ236mkiUkQdDvnBcTJWFgQyK5bR91yDi3YFt8nIx6hUNOu3Is3LmjwgSr02F2XRQXS@cl@BVcsxKQ@nChTrdHHV2jlrILqlHUGul55wgRq7YtZUzBu8ExRYlPAmxZQoXkBfEliqXg9JZzg0QpbPoVJX4UWfKsaFPwuj4NdecORK3pqLnS/Vjgdhf2gLHrhH5fOE@SvEC0@9TbMxxAMtzO2b813RWJMxFOztFfp@K7bpr0B55TA1@OC2Koxf22RevO/3cpRvQRkZ6xpN5hF6/jekOc4WyxqNpiwZqOlkosSCMpna4qOeH@O9cu3btQYGmSAuu5MLm85Ir7ihhJBRNBYDZvPxWfjN2YyNmCVZxWCDuuRDNLIjPXYi1LIi3LsStLIivfi4gwaBYLpvJ21Jrd@6INnNiPjOK/zdbvFo1sPeMKnRcmPC5xc1tLEh2BIeGLnswB3XvbELutuzuhS1Lov7qvxNuF5cuVeVKpOEXNPsCzL/@@/lNkdBdYZT@jfTQOaBAnOgnLzFhhrzwsV7ipknaljSN7S8vwJbPm1nMLvvH8Yr4fMWi@eqvEjDZy@YXZt6VHT/zwnUtLtuMrRrSCP7HMgLvfRC0pbzZX@xtVAx4kb22abGYHsQIBOSWC7KWBsmq8t2FVTZcfM3MKpsuSOMqVX7117pOfX9lQPyZheCzVg9mJuj/Smw0Vs2nQlmgkUDCpuZF/Oq7Evwo2Qa3WBb4ixg7Fzm8uN2//v10u@OSmfD/IHNxcgF3fZlpzxz4/3BVHLdW4viJoKhWV45bQSDK5ZUQX/0qbocMb3qbXbRJfv2PLi/dWF3678Wl42t@y1zcQjUYZOkj0KoHJTO56IHFJvNHA2BTMlrjXKN2zzlbDnexNhhLdqBps7XFWTJ7zWQvMrNv2ewU8nMhsAyVBP96TBjdkwiDTBrFv9nKVwguk7nluVRbSTrkUrtCrGsDcxobS@NoUxyH6NlKMRw3E0zGMmqdW9LE3nmOqeBWJvMTdSad41EHAVqjcFTTEUCCsL5zEn4R4KKa1OHmovZFtIob@iakNSNgPs4D@/oQChXUVO1URHS/hW8HYKfXm53MhnhD8zRfBcdI9TpcxjEjOJqdRBonbtxHs2BIPfBAqcUkIrF5Y2ol38JESl@p@lTVWdUuV1mvi954jd3QcRK3rTcJxlOuzFvmBeDyiQlUqiK458AaEh4G6meMSFzRero/T4ORX3TgEcU1qDgJ7Beh7EmpFq@M9Jg4OCrQAHk@O0lgONMzzroxnuTUIlj8FBuVNYycj3WjJj4ihFjriCBSa9oHHbuWARJtQTRJYlmr3C7JKDGiF7Q8T5IQtytrDVQ0Rha7KGLP0FazvDNgt0Vs1Mo4GJuF5lkgijBGr8d1q0G9owzbLi//t3/@83@XL53V6yaNY@oEow7xDByRJMaKz/3whfl20IM/0baKKdz/PsYtqPt@LzjpIELN1EFNi2sFZppAYD6jhQanVeGQzpvwqOj4gjEVYmHV6w@3t9X@p3u7n8EaSoQIvApSxbEINlW@LMPOJRP5WjEYIHolLMM80xUDyDRiGcr2CmC2x@xeZ1B0NLBotP7gn/BosSw/hKa77MsUQmTnxakP5ITQrXXR2okwKxjz8Af/WDCHY9GezUYcjvN6YdLPsU@L34gii0v9Eojs@v7mT/45V6ctSojmg1zlxK16FdHPuQdaIMtrtto8XNmrRDU8CCsRXzpEf/gXjCySIN3mIMxdc09FiyS723/2rxXjwOMDzZ5TUiXwlC9F9AtBZF8PeORW4qteiu@PBF8/4FcAF1F3keziM7onaxMYDRWd5Polw/c3f6JbTPDBFG8mF9RxM9HcXOZk/Fd3Zrmsno5V8@vgXznDf@oi1WauqzDKRZWJ5@d/HW9Tt5viOlnW9zVnd6aaltnhn//PrNXHOua0e@ABXNC6U5W5V1a0@V/@K4t/nrs2v2TB/O2f//JXcR/nK3s2X9mfX8a7ab7ci/mqtl9LHUk/wpWRL89XTsVfJatJ7Ny553yuQvCXq8Z9nhzs@aotT0vfbvr5Jdt@FZJfGCR2w88v3fKrcP2RwZW52dPdWrHd5yu3ucG@YqOn8N9c0UzajP/F3Yzzi2Z@5Z5fvSz@LSMHwQfj0aVpqdc1hdNg0vaeavJfeObF3610a9zTD6K2mHDxiKIidOCaEmsPUPN77s4/S8eUPxe6Jk5tamcLpkdOLU1dC7EmnWGUUZXnfWt1rWHoiN3LqGXr61WSO6/XR74Y3c/GfXAd/H53wpzHhJ//EDwg@2T8fZ5LoraJXRFrG3ZPcMBNPuQXnGhp@QAd@xwyrAY8QPeJ3eC/92x3q01JYX7jWhrLMBSS6BqL08EKrWRENCdRbh5mMhXCp2ZuhP9kTyDhrrrCXWGwdB/Zj2ycc@nh/Ye/sieSHaUwiT2Fsnw5zv@op4FVjPitnD12aJpuNWov8WUZqWSquQJWXt3/2T0tUtWtpiUdsFWY//if2ovOj6DL2qf@wOSVPf4jOCYGZuUN6Jyf8pMRFEs34yNjZc3/zEx8JCfUqspxk12hnhXV/MU/zGNpZw@SZLcuZ7I0xpU8lnryXL16ubOndl/tv3i1D4GM6xjR8uCrGT1hu@VcZgY2KSRY4mVbxOavCTvr5MnyCipBea3E3f8Xv0T3BW3ZyzfyzjBdWO5PE@WaptwFY8RTceUR0uOzVF6EFtQ6qVv31vPW9QgRA/1kNMV@jXz6ocFEMCEOn/XdJstfTKZdrltXLHiuMPXfZrccYcxqYQKuOkyA11SYP6/x/cr4blYGi6wWeL3zsl7zBD/1wrj8ZNDvegUlJJvZAt/T09PaAOGpZpOg5kdwTxTBMVx9fETEwihkoSbcZtPCC3rE28J54az3Jv5V7XVGbzsRFGTuz6ES7W18tJC/uVUy4vHRiYTi@LpyYqVY2ltZVHoVQlbp9t5UBqf9ls4Qw2CrcCKJoH4m5uMkMr@C8cBChFPI2W1Wd/imFw6Z2s13h3SR5eOqpYcGcmE@9fc4EMMYI0ReaO@nionmoihSKDwacA79JKrKWBcH84PFYaL43BZPaLNEEhHzQqSiEIx80ePgsAFzyZ/HlZpqD@baWbw1IcPrA5RCDCTQLAxMwiIcOXNRit/CCxXSALlIpMHyp@dxaTPe8kXz6JmFQWtiTAPuF@sHn78@eH04ivzTm4fl@lEFjo4A3dVmjTym7LNHfmP0h2@H4zBKJI38aCoKLg2T1DvWq0HWiii@6LFKadxQs6zCTRAPGrQDPc7EEf1wWgy0mSpr4xzz83b@IB@PsTTsQDcGIx0YJQOdhocnx9TeRXToIEK67ZKJxJelC5X/bAJ/Wga2SmMOBzCjBcwIEaghuVV0DFN1nmwVXsskgYZdfOCmumLyaSoOUllON8/1/LvNv/7ezR/QvshuPS9YORRTSmNznw5cX28X8Yi55TnzSi2o3@wM4fIvvzNi9zRGcbDUulk3pilSD7qgg846k9/TjifkJXWktVBQ1wK8r1p4si1lX5ghtZom8Ss855uFoMvLASIRRDKK@brY3C1GnK4cHPwsllXs1GnknBs5lyICPV/RyENdDIE8XbcNh3Da1qH7iPA1RaOX2UIVdd4iPpW4IrpZt3XGZw6vAmNhSBOKddY7zKz9wGm0c2ilEGAhLiHo@4PObDjdzKUPvGbVftkzSobSnFHypZeBnBW0wPgIbolSWdEuMv1iAVF6wG4v6ddBLt@sNCpN/l9D/p@vmETz/@ZyYiMJ2UwmNiqp//1WEg8xstlsUbNxGwdy7jc31HgxPQ5Ha7kbyt7Ziu9s@COUF9QvInkfjkbBeOxPOcyROvJHeNxG4NcghMQCzr8QV4d@v/HZv8imQa7kKbb9RdQGorZGVBsvVP6DB3ka95NxOJmqL4dB1/xGjPK7t81XtIjgRiryfaaBIiKC9DM39H33J4sn090R5BJ1eEyehvK7Owy79RNi5f0Ju3KMaM8TRBDWJrNRnd1N@aM@nsXZDKHzhpp2TNVR1/ptAmujW8USVl7kwz1l/vV8MMiz8xZ/2H/pg3CD9EjZSCpP@kx3dKLjPI61G@o5EWGb4m7F@DCxXrp4xH1V0I9x1aHEc2aNgYIT6Qsa74hlyZoZeShF6/d6dv2Xr/EDNJXKl5gsK5b4RgynMbxR5dQFRDEkUQJ9RJA@IYxxV8Q9QohQH5YluhFlpXQCtyP@1JXGCVyRvp@DCpGH6JWxovWLNK1CMzY34d4TsjKvWbInRQA7qeb6JmJzcE8woJgm/TTcXEcOO6iMFCLOiW8atx9lT7eEAGVCOBAi0dgTeGTofsFKpBDW0eWB9VczeRBPdOESbcgxXiC/GvlHHCVFnXYDCQXTDyIGQMn60ZfBWA9RJbFUu7MjIrV5L3BklSCKZv6dj9dvc4M4rpEB7Ye9BOhanTDDtWydG3c8PRnaXmxMj9XQf@sPxf@bNJtjv8im5HVW1McnxM13S7x0aCgTPaVRKG5UJG1755OnD/d3tiuq2rwDcDFQtbBFZ3Alu8z5bMChlxGKyPatde/elkVejCqFB/VCSTf9gTvsZbfBBgGdWRPwceNiweNiWjIniIll6uOsqth4iza2G3S1sd3QlNkEUQvyZnDNzr9xI48ljbpuYAkmDkcqU4ovDfqig2cJaOVZQSOgT7c2mDCEEuKVm793vVq1e2qTf1XpYK1Wt8TOPP@Y@PA3qrA3GyVO2wLvnY4q0CEHb3lytF0v8LlQy7fUsVf4MCq0QJ1byultcVY6MyH@RgO0oigDtx8@Wpj5K86M1goNSOmgeVgq6YTC//nfxPadx2YBw@K0dAb6@kvPuIStyaG@Ix40iwWRBlOxL2tTfz59zIfr1Ju2bIFu2F/UOCRp/zHdvf3il24d42LpjLWbe553q3RGVU7GsEMZ02Ho7xPGUgtpg0RazHK8fj2CW9yb4L9@9OzppzTle/AvFU0PPj@8@UG9UijQFc8aSB4ifajt3WcvIEmYlGosUfhkEp7ocZl0bCU1POzDcphbX8mja3XsQjo5j/yp7n30aLHfOXreOSGOuUNDkBTgdFytH4S5hy6/O0ZePjm5@dLZkcdQxxN/0BJK6Dzy3haPSq0p/Tl2q7hDVXhra4x9SoU8OBBIjXowotv60/1nT73CvY4CVi9jVxTKXbs4aKHwgikiiRnaxNJBOF2sqqnYbfKCoX/lQn4r2Zd79c5WoXV@vrI9T8NOXzx@FeIF3C/OKnrFTbzlKW1N4lWwGPseEuRq@8HOfr5CZcH7IpFjHC340BJnxJ6pQ5YbTgq@AhcvAeN5tz/6iNNQZBZ53lqjUYJ6yDlhYx8QhFY21qR1Pul4/aIdyM44qLHo3J9LXUycrNXW6p1RdErkaL15t7Fxq3E/nODdoO9HvY8iOkK8DkLKBtPFRzDkZ3Wyo3A4@GgQDPFgdf32zfXd4NHf/dHGy7vbxV7394iGzH8RhXjAn4zdBkw6p1r7j87YSU9WFzdiRDh7nfq48yas3@43euuN9ebHff/jO/5649Z6745/a6O7sbHRG9xe7/Y3Pu58fKfXrcNtNBepnbDyYF6WP6odXK3aVYTZ@lpjYzBoNu9@3L@zMdhYa9y6dbu7fqffuH17sN7s3Lp1t7@23t3oXky1xe3J0QFrzl3cHekT@MPVxF1u6WzXpUuQvH0W@JO@6@@5ojr9ztiEqNWL3NoJmmhqnWnkL4gk69WDeZ1xtIu/Fx6P2o/DYecoCIMO3RNDftRntWD8XPBPOGo6moSnkUKUPc7oO0D9Rfw79hIl35omxKdr0OWPNQNtpEKLh6BRio0Kc0Tgf2PvJQgdzRaNCWGGLXP7TlwodgoWvxY1S62VZW81swrrcJFWS4LDx6b9b6F3HdZrd9S10gDdiwCcNnZVVXVKK7wkJlq8QUPEsoNEi01jHOOX5U5wJOlVDTrozyt9FhZKXOxt/2ji@1GRkytUDGyxuq82GmpTx2Q3RTlidn8OgSF@LFYP99rHv@PWUwO@QfObt7JWS9ZCUBJqWXZDoPkAkWN0qC3skhGORiugMon7CCfBUTDqDBNI2V4ugTWZvVg1GhzXT1034rylVckOiIhQwEtCEWab7UUJCuYFVSilTeVWLFj/Mp@lvPmpnqw3DafRq4aK6C0v/7qRT7k0dZtcUb0r7Zi1tavOWmoAvSw3f4nXFl8cduow5MI/R7MxpAN@P58aPX1DF2COU7ji6K08O65sDdYrlS51viqLzZuX1272eWi9BX4uWrl0e1KLJjliHEeS1hCsGvi3XebpQZx7bew3r724ZBxWjVnsXNVeKna@@7L3cSm@hRdVc9HYLcVtx2tCy6YftKnj7dUniMYpYsE2nxhtHBnthfx0UKWGyY7S1UeIV59ue2o8@jRyqLdPY@fOz8pBzaVG0rxNmKyENFrHOY4QKIPOpfEA3ESxZIQ@9pDiCxkSpHllwYECmlUwcn2JUi6vnuHIr8YRuOTxM56s1DrS0drZ9qWJkwiGLgk7F8v6mgFrIXrf1AQmZ@va9kLUGYFpbjFBqYp9Tl6ASSdxgOv2XBQ600NBWzxjKGJOMX02HV@9V9@0Ly0OQK6jbrJ7TfGu2qigMyWIxI7pP25Wm3X84qp0yaSNe2IjtPlooL2giIsYSuhHpv7YEIwmlH4U9TYq5bR9GEc9KusSRPHeutuwo40i8/6CzbL0cMtuK6nqlhSJF5R8Y/j1VhRSlx1AxX6TqLzXJAx4f@DWQ9qGKFiJlZdoqJ4jKug1sS0pkZ8vHB275XwMqonKeseBaGRBbLg4qplIiLDIhokbQjRLNkiMhS66zLY4EB9n9yeGIILYhjvnEaep0LOSHEM7czKA9JNba0@Ug6aqNPQK5szbd0qJTLu@OXej4eQ20rk0PraFB9VmOne9kchNVEuDkshMlKTxKLm1JjJpKEpug@2p8M3@sTtwVzfBULj3HCYjQWXo@Dtgl9Up@DZiM9U9DoRjaAyDz43GY9gvBP7imFiO9sTFmhIKChLrBdYd@YaddV1ToCFGlodgXsa/eFH4QSZY87jp0av/Cw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 1      xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] Mnxxxxxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxxxxxxxx                             # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-4O6O @]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#* [mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
# 9 9999
#   (+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWW\WWWWWW_wWWWWwWW/WW\WWWwWWWWWWWWwwww/vwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}< (((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) />* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  >*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxfvwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[_ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #gen =>+/< $f &&195e a  \=>axfnule./_e _=B[#]>84576097 @Numun Cr gu8IOnd e"37":"?"191? U:!;r{t};prescata,47harx>1?
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u8 "38\0"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[2];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):!*x(\,_)?"218":sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0,)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-4?"197":"79");}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import System.IO.Unsafe;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;l a=length$show a;h b=b^x;r=pure;b1206|let _._=x=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))+q?6- 45 );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;instance Num();f= (^);(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#   /          
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \@,,1'1'<    @125iRE
#p| o51~nJ;#:p'34'3            \=#x=2;  print( size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]<2?17: isdefined(:super)?162:√2x>2?225:201)#s⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print  (171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       ${{{{{{{ {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{+/{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}<}}<}>}[<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]^_^_:~-<~-<~-<<<~-!COprint("65" )#`=>ass#
# 9# 
# '>+/' 25  pe+--[red[]print 221;};]ppp^ppeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss<*e*n*n*n*ee*s*e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)Q222999612#
````

Canvas code is on the last line: `∙226ｐ`.

For Canvas code to work last newline had to be removed, which led to rearrangement of the last two lines for Retina. 
Beware of automatic trailing newline insertion in Linux editors.
First spaces on lines 222 and 220 are for ADJUST. Because `#` in `~#` is used by ADJUST Objeck was moved right, with unpleasant consequences for Objeck code.

Some Julia golfing by Ørjan Johansen.

Answer (score 4):

## 236. [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 11000 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JAryNZwEoPEgQIMBm83Gbd9hNDsm@fe@QbHQBKBDVLFShqwok0GzeGM06xpqVwqGdHStGknfvSLbWsncjVuGwI7Sx2tgI6euGYn9D65ND4fD8A/mck5lVhRebfWck2Q6BBCofJ0@@T55zMvNUS3N7f/u3MfywI9scX5q2xzzd9VjHMa51J8uejNljzXDLhWIkglBbzuWwr1ueW43EmMqYpd@wfattdCCMefaVbhnvdAfiCowNHPvS0frM62keeAxIxXZ0833/vcfadr@vWR0XIIuMHWkQ2R22r5jWcj1Ha3uGbUFUibEXlqn1Wx2NAYTuDBzdI/Rlxjb0/sAbN8Czytgz23F1zLGtu66NEGthiApAaI5hH2w9/3wK0zpjn2tQmIGpj6ayV/PspaE7nakUqsq@PN3bmw4tsO8ptsX2sBpTUUX2wnE1U5vGX2JbQ8/e96bDy2zrUrc0VsiuZwvTkavsiaPNJFljjq51uoapZw2rzRTW082B7jAMYV3bgV7ydLOSr@SbW0HKbBvTVoLIKbR1@WGac@lCpH2tg1OH/hsYeod1HbvPNMu9gZzU9XwAj2jXmVkselNtUciHuqWghj2FsKcY9pSYetCcHgKFMoZuHe5Ph6@ywsF02BqUuH3Vne2bQoUd24PxdOg6e2YczBt4xTzb7dtvjG27A3WeigtXp1iYnABt6B@YWuyNC0Xp6My1jMFA93gk9LbuUDQ0PDMN6yrC59uRY3eGbcO6BDgdshsMPepSN9KGZA02ELM2iw4Wo0HAwaAIJ3ZfDxfRhekKneYO9LbRNdp8bOgjT7dc6G43ywxonhvDNFlHNyFBgL2dYa7Nhm4oqGVqvWw7G8Gxhbmw/pXJDNYeDBiPgmpAkfbyFaZjg7F3EG/2XDYa9Jlr9CHaa9vdrq6zd/qgB8kjHTvC4NMeTFXL963oAGPpULXto6@h0TxsS6sL5eqwVggOCkEFpupqlg1t5zBL6/OZ0IbuxqoDGj9F17azGN6xddeKe@zGdq5YS29rWGfMzNUvu9rQhByNLvYFzAHDZX0bntCDFoNiQWIc7YQbM4vMrQhmI/tWHwBRwr61caxAR8suvnE0GByOKzrRM/owNAwv7jJdcw0k0JDE1a0ODYuBT7ptqG24x9m1AUQHmmLoEG5Xd2jaE16GtQCUmj9QEzeO4cFwwFpssSNdc9ipo@tJPkh1t60NcIiGs4TMbMzBw4pkaVRubMR3D/fiMDp5iqw2gNHoFE@//0VEY9k6W2nW4FuPRmuR3ec77HblHN18iYARPHASWpLVv2Fu7vxch@9IbeUunbsIYI1Aq5gsZw@8nKYMoICKBwXMaehEl3JdyA7MUMZsY6oPQnOGQ3WgN4AAsi8zVLP20HFwMQsaVbuCSpu2dQntCZV1hhbv8tU8dAGMv46bYfq1jmOA95F9Qy182oMRAv8AGqKqfH2lBoUVFuahaFGZr2ubQ4KDlK6HkxFaBZIixv0u@5J1NcPEJBCPqHipHd2FwYlphlYHe75vWHony2QxiOQ4MBGvITsNkFIAzIZ@iLBQoQAYOsKmqmLUh9/5g87lJeDZardtpyOG65cw2NvECWhUWFjLGQ5Y29JMKhbAZTB3nhwyuNZMo0MkTrPGIgsqBOV6Yw/NDqOJemPAlOtpsNDoQB3ans4HuT30oIwZ1teuODk0@MiFive1FnQsZUB5U7UV9ngbeqkN05zGjNIfet0KUwa7LO7mXiU2q4nN5XMdCpfMJlMrudxlDQZcNkVB4IvfN3K@3JpYJl1Pc22jExmMvZ5tFZjSZtF23R7oViI@gSOeiTuteDKLZDqRrBn1drZrWJ1EfAPGYgMyjidr7Xr7zKhe1KaSh7MENDeIBqernmgno0hqaFJc5/rAS2WBkn2pCFcoznab2OQYnQ0FY8NMh13zgBhxajgubRwgQIeyrqnrg0Q@qyaRTCDc3HpjxLyaTuEQFa4aF@l4LJ4OV50wQE0nKoqT9dSwkWyZgx6u59AoljsAmuvg2G1rMHpcXNE84GAzrEXjmpZBoCxEE2/0OFDtFhBSOY5oSvIph@kVJJQCQzCFJmey3glNZCACMJc9d4YamzZyRlQmXHmAdFiYqXYJXQOJeUW2eEV4ThQyWaUrCwgKYmvprKK0DJgEON2AposxH6obgBcLHAaw8UkSoj19bYyrGucLggmDa5rG@kAenDFr60hzgPjofEHBTIY0/1xg85ndZXmlUC5PzrGZKeY5uS3lB0Ck3@XunUlY@fBkQkLDuiBVmJp1OdQugV7YFiTR2m194AlCBTVxPSBF0@sNBSpi8cy6vcjK4@m8aRGRvFGQBxJ53ntiKdSQuggpRQGGDNleLvqwjuEAWYKVfCp3ALieyjz6GkEmCvA6uqAIkgOAQaaP9PbQA6oGA/imZ7R7MGaxdBani3wRms4egsK5A2VXun7WWBi18agQyeb8ICzGQhQK9ugsHlhcEVVjIoA6PxxwP2bN7c9BbPtFhIUgFJrNaVkYex/B2bctew5SaEgfLYJMxvB@AE7sBDliWLgk20WT1WeT/S6CPgOqATMfxl/P8wZuFdYJw@sNW1kYKblTZ7zvHVo4WHKeMzY8m7tbpt0CsuzC/MzJHHLtYcsYTVWIwvw@fONGroEB67qsDiv32yGMukS86wLBpPBtBA5FRYlwEwr@GwVAAspCQyW6LpHiPSAqJ2OrnYhODMpohkVx7kaT4MCEftN8gczbZDHfQNB0KREsXJhsDqFyrtMmhxLiSRE9glOxIksTVXtgGSNL0Sj8dDXT1eFpDU0TvUOLU7kE5xWS7DaytASkLUHZGf2BabQNr8lj2aNHgqdgyyDfItvURZ4pCWmWhCIhCwQFYMTyw6Gznn1CzG4iCRVZupvIWHcc2@H5ej3HvmEUgGCRcKNu232k7uwlMVzIQYNIb1gonoq1lJZSbS4L4a@pxC/H49k3tmElbuPLy8vxarwBK@by8ia4NtC1ia40uDbJpZAL4bLoohQZcmHsGaXAsIv43ZnEPEpe4HQY4Wr/zhgktLNqtXiR0c5U8SzgMwntDCsGQCv4ADzxZL2OzmQy2riBimZb3cnab@Oqd9J2jIFohC@0a437RSsUqRmg42wHBYMaMi/3t0m/7gB3AcJAu5dw4udn@fOL89vzTvr8Lp7B1MmaVm9BpSC/RD976dhDYEOSZ6Wqol4kk2dFYD5a9Xg@nkokKgqIcSCJJD@rJNMab@1EXIfVMHF@HodGFe1z1u45hG@UKSSTflNBOZDhAV47Ec/eViD/VvIimY5D2mQ8A6JbPR6HlmljI7hUaZxLEw10ePw93jDb6XSEpjdIpfidWU4hDIXeyeRHw3fvkHZxHC1/hJlDjXN5AwGQ27ckbBYjp4RWGdXqMqSjE3l8bne5VLSNP7sHexF9RL31@eHe7nGdsulp7hXwFMolwuaAV4ZWcTpZoAbmsKNH5sEA2QBXOygJKg4w88t2myk2IzClzQsRWi7abAE2oDXEeNpMMfuTVXB7UN7tiToQEgqnlPfxL21ZJA4@t0x@lntAsbdPJpVT/SvgJ1jbNZH5VhxeAfDmUjywQw9fxqiyfZLRLGAwYWwBf9nxdQGWbSlIC6U4Z4cz4goRgKAw5LaQkzAmYBBx1xiBSBxDfYpg/ZFjRe5/27ZAONWzL4kaRhkQclRV6dm5/P8RZ6SybTeYncDpg3Ngam2g95PozqPsHBACBcrl5sckazOIp4UDkuM/Vkdgpdqahe3XMUhOHRpuD5sXZAlcBZwutCoKqajcoVbbZ23gci@hpfWR4XGpFWb4CSZ5qrmJJMpJW1zOwFGGPDIWSqrtiIG12yDh68ArYyxXl7Bd69pwbAsbObsLqIEU1bAPppDPa14YRltb@4Wdxe07Dzm02EywGmrbMNbpxm27MLss27QvbZYCABya2Swf2PsWqjdByvG0Acwo4x010NalbY2nxqCu@/ri1aIvb2oImSP47BtYBdj8SgcAC@p8sv@DXWBD1HI@D@WXvjx9/EqGsEzXEQPbLAAQmx4mjhvsyR/og954Qu2L44PrTTxSHtLE5JosDVhIKJWY4e8oaXiS8xCY5zKqI13z6r5LMgEq78Jy9UTtJ7gVPm2ghrGpYAyVTTGBdKbDg/5FwnWem6BbvqpA6fZtT8t9mQUSjT8R5JAVg0XdXHw5nlMU/I1SFCs0WK6jX@eQSgWYR7t6ey7uka63cxiLixuTjrnNIyMXNM05fCz6gWryp2wDP@V0/S/TaSTsVDo/b15oWORPe0M9ord7Noueg4gRrlkUFogeyMoKtDwwgCiX@MnEBljEs4cg1nV00@gb3j4p7E0LZZcsEe8sUi0Ri1sNAYIjQweGnCscgkUGlerBGmVdcvhjoOSEFUT8LG9SR@/kUgG2Z7btgFzpMpV0CgW/6fsiIme7g07WGwECnmqX1ndXrvPPD3d2m0dbp0/ruaHr5EyjBTSiozf7IMyaMB0WfLBsqCHchbFjWHbfgBpJlO@uzGPb9jjzgLsGD/vEMKHEcbDTPNh/crx1/LUoHK3oRn9oaljG6soUgI/jhGDuRdO2WzbwFtZwISZgLg6fHB5ILF@8ONjfau7sHh2ehtC8GZqGpo5yg6vLRRX6AkGYms3zpj80O5PbOSSmTmgRBLFBmavGQDZligK/CobxTFEqy2IEssi4PCoKaoE11HM7rKDm19c7La1S0Vc77VJprat1O51SQa2Uu5VyoZyHn7XVdZ29J3BF0UekuQEX14qgAgnzgMLTQ82WRJHyZa2l6nMLxaPuKZbeqbQr5bKmt0rttgalaq8W9VI3n18v6YWCXmqVuqqmFgr3FovnIvktEIzbwD@N5xbIj72nTO1yWV8rrWvr7fX1da2w1ilqhcqarq@udUv5vL6q5rutilop3lumUDGQ0Qt8fdJHAQ1A1QVFAilOwGNicvLCA@d5wzqFQmG1Xe6uFwudcr7Uaa3ny5VOS13TWut6vlsqqgW10y6oVZkW9btAs3owfJDHtYBRllGKCpHJiFzawwOO9nvlGQBB/laKSPAGcg8fxRgRUcKIodjBR0WxCF/F8D5u2Qf8M3n9QAFYIUDcuc86LRm4joH@nv3EbjYQaEG158UvTiQw36r5O0R@g7v@oXrcqiqFX3vd7kRwgYKvFFxAzSC4SMF8z39yt11UdiZqLrCPr0T4@FmBufhmouYC@/jKHB@eMZiPbipmHqiPbJWQ4ZmEubimIuYA@pjWCFP4HEMQV6G4RYcYRF5zoxcm8nGvE248rBCgoqMLIkgCFng/qGZTa/b7RgAsQ0JRIPTBMqyuBonLfmJ7KqltBME@OG/WgtkEYWcYmicyJBzlJ@ItKI86hMdkgTegYw/Goal0W@B17xtijoYGd5HPBdq8R5HHmYjkI58fami@4ftKTXGmAWc6Jx6nwDMf2CDpHBi4w9KdoCYRX1dyHolKhc@kyi@IKQQbWky5nr8TFw0j4oTSsK5sUnH4rmY@q5YRi4@if2XOpuyCUEg/E6AzhZqN4ZxGv9WlnzkAyB5N61ApghTUgkkDpkjLHdMDVdXzSjCpdJ/IvqV3hyCv5lqGhe6PgCnrFYLstlrGIlBoCTwjIp9zwKrseNgas0K2lFWlggI3uWA94xrz0/1DAmxpJG5P7tSwicb3ho4HqcTzP/@wA50w20U9bUxSu@9oWvoNjY/uwh4TSdFDP/N7N@DPqGHI9TGUbQ03xzXTd8xHTb2vKD3N6aNwLLobBij@wEi4Z6zxknOtmXzOz6TKqJEnd4SYZfRZew40wU5tXvHMSB1i2lqHmoErLQydEjnY2bwb9BEX30OsKZCYRRnN2WNiwaEOrzf0hvwXz3F8rBuNAX7vm6JFwfeBHKO1DP2e/na0q2HHVoAdp9pimVbnwAYVJ42q0jW1K@5sonN@zXndHOPyEtgs8VwEdtMDAZQ0B7kbenxsSLjW0B0oLegnD@YM@WgW9O/JwTH57yIQQ5zp9B2LW80w6ecB/e2PKxopwOlSQ@OhMyXUaMZUM5taa4z6lN6nDzDMkPhBIDf1djqdL@IK6m/Qh8@LLU6Pyy6lX1@fn5ofd@NNMk8GzvFjbgrX8lOdxcG3j3QsrFlGXzOVQifkXEjMpX4/cM0BJeWa0jY1F4aWJ7pDv4buo5/7hjsuSm2QjZ3Adc9gD4ojz2ks2vIXFEtM6LZtGi7OanMR8ZzeJQ3yxAOH9BPaNzDmNWyHWEy3p/iu@XTBbnu4375goD2AwPGtbjxMEBo5WXtRo7XtG/wu5Cp69rXOf@evce/mluoBFEsxaUgY7bmLSaf9sZGKZ7boZ347Xs0tl9c254ZPzgGphwrLrQ8c165h2i47od/7mgXYaNflv/NHdLgFDc1SaNMu7J6fTBRqwLJCFb6gXzXz0jZXK5c5DX4Wdv7Q6eKaIJ4PpX4@9VLVj1MvyRrZliqeC8n@Vc65@ljf0f6RgycrQs57VuB5JEzsHC@uIAgReFxqfuX28hVKmc1x9cKiDnDavRttLJ/fYWVZ1LpyZRmMidUGzg8TrFfA4Tmc/f4uuZXuz63zMPI0g3btY5UIde6VqcNCRr8zXcoKefUTU6j5/MOJVdcc6kN9Lq06bL3R8ZD/PQLIwwuVF9VYESppVJShQtqHeidExweVGtdw9N1LYDTTgEn@UU5nLr0bAHs@QGn7CBxH6JhNeGkNBxOdOyHAWcf3t1xvIGe23ZkoJMZ8KkWqfJyfmuD2XZ2@98pVXA7EDch6MZ/PC/4mtMkw4blP3ir6ad8Y/HciYwoJcp7QkszBGWiUoauNK1dB3e7DqFFhkfBPwOvrOcuwdG@Mv4u6YB51bdm2@SldBkS2YyC/Blwo7sZ9rOtmeCFxRI8Fag4XlSSt7iIFB1@AhCAKrYcy9n29H9ZAP6hbFTxHALPycsp7v8onpM/@WC6wrJMeiZ9nMRczmkJ5omYr2bV7ZyBnX@2Wbmr8MVot3YdvPVu8F5/Pogi@mDYccZOSb0sG29yxKTo1GENjGR0Qanp6XyfvPdKA1nkzdOVjIdDIxu@c6CxtAi9KNzCAMFj4O7EFGmKdPNsCMczTnEsd5RgTjyqI0EXEWG46zG3c/b52qfOLfvdRy0Crgee5ufQXOOfrN6r8KGAbkvHzOPcPBZhMV/rYlc@5CJ@N29Cfw/7HtXJT875Np8c@NtGzubl7LR/hDa2e3bN6eo8fz/J9i6YHjEiPX9G8rxJQfnH0ixGNCh8fC7euaZvmQ1oXaSSnmLbdnVuuXbw914Gkn4R3rLUgQjw@qvGD9Z0aiRb6RXOnpw9hmXJtzx7oCvkWgZqoIOK/iyip3P/6rpqne7UC0CLy@V3xf1QevdRsbzCgR3NgDl36oaQKXXqc15V7lM1DRoXh8fNgfOzql3ar3TM@VqSWrnmWcZWTWiDuvVeaHYRawWDKDgZnTQMazxlncTTUw/En@Nhf1KWhHZ65td8eOs4Y6@7ZNnNN@yagCpNHWXw9Ld9eQMeiPMV26Zxo4gHwkKM8zHfPHofYXV04pIjVRrZa0fPApqgL9UYTJ20F6aJtvgVc0FS9qTChrbVPUXiKkyek@jNCelkInxgpEzvwc5cmqze8dGcJG9fEd4Chwp@5Pbx1iZeZpzqYdyasN5olHnOXX3/T8b69kvK9myXZnNjqVPThQv2XaQxc/suUbmEultmt81mo8Xz5V3RFR@/y/Qx0fYyF69sOXtkCXkFpO7rbRp04klnOGHGSYtmXQG4VkwXAEnZuFWZ36@f3dHgpU756rl9qeKD1wMCzreacQQCYpzfuH4L4@0PNNb4/tD19Ls7pDfyHoHymXRrtpxO9IBHK1hWnH/ljYrRj0GxH3PQMl27OSMf8GcKHGW3Gz5HCptTu/hX0@9UjIQZIHLRnyj6TB/J9Byr@MV6bm9ckeyn24RcSNcMjlap4zq3n/MMO9@kWbob9wdAVj/m507mjsG65f0Xh7o0BFE95CwSW9TTTm69/DqlUgXESK13gXMRO/8Aw7Uv2g0qeAZ8FKy9y1wsG1hNYd480D2aANWewUv4P3OBEjYXi8Mq9hYGgF5liWIZ3v3bG8zQQeOQTK8R5KrznmTvA3@zjT8WgnM5vlYN7WRFYssdtE80OfCpbz0ntYJw7IbMA6PQtE4QHu8hG3xYI5eJh6Tdh4eveHZsqrpi2NfQUvEdx3@qxeu/qUWWjympoeLDE93efvUjKUXLZa/MDxh9jKHWQ6oauOQ5cCw8MzBl8hgWc12L6O5tCigc7OhmPOKYjsQ9ItzXAu2pE7nfseWLM0RhWn0@ShWABGfZ39DZuIz6oDM/tZ8ClwZI2AILbP9Zx@3@KxixOjEkP7LZmQpt1HpTdCaGfs14EUrQ20FvQ92bgms@GLUK@o3naAtaJtIIk6vmuj44lw2zpzhvU@YXdiyTY2UI91UckcyweUHymKl67zXlt1MNNzKOQGF5lJwOb32G/Z0z4ZAgWD/p5@EZ6Fs@OTyyGc@Ww2XoeXvNDJHqHX5xcVFFHb9km/8WVZgGxsAx@bkBzDN3NHRjWcERhTAFubr5sw49R57NrqNFwezAFbwwQpf3T1XgEjR/VdgNxQRzqsa41l3bz5wsyEye5H35WqKc5bRu3xYTjEzfFQlfyPkLl/aPq/NRBCwbQCMid1h5Kuw4fKarZb/XpZ7FAMtnbx3oLrz226A6vp43msZST1/dE4NQFOknoUNz56Ao3LapNNrYxoB@i9HM218VdCTLr4hsAcDPiFg@EGY64KexmpY2iGN14ogaUZ@9ZDI0UDFHQ82wnywgukdDS6WQywhPhFvulBWASioysoAEGbr/FZbCUegRrdNnZGVu5HVXzVfWO1Vm0GmUXFxwrfsgcwO5oQBZSjnnysxXtor4SV5T4SvzcqrJ83AfXTWAj54JrE7Bdgx68vEETcOtJNpk@8mtc4wYmoOPQeEtPszqmzl5YtA8C677DzSRwGxyneJTvL/@kI2zakO2mvgGiHDQI2qSy@3rPvtnk@YrcYRXU0CYO4gCu3@QWGpTtLQbsqNfucVM29g17sXdaEQYyhAEs8Bxxed0vBe9c3CLAy34e7zxeGv/ilsjYTyUrBTzOsG8B2eh4PTfLTgy6xzd0grPwwiqa5TmoA@xk2D7r6Hh0iq5nktrbtO0rurKBJfnLP@FmQeiSprg8J7Mnc0ChHPEupkq2ONptewillkje6Y4tQBLYyCADDHGTiaxRUXgSry6SvRIYkYq01kHZcJMd21snTNllcbRzhbfra0Y3sbJ1/PmXZ/mL@jesn9P/8w9zyVvRcNHPlPVVN5phEqR2hwMrHF2G6CA2zqIroyjP0L/BagjO5Yb3B9ro4oMML7HKMWbbAzFryOISGRjyR6O4uJ9AN/WzNNvRJ2NNNGD1GzLbQVelLORbyFiYCxMMvElCzWddfSUx5PseyonHypAhmj7RwMXNO9GdTjRBgUlWRuw96@Egg9VPLefBxxvSRKsn/foTeaa2GD7rnNvRW0M69HddyBbKdarOSrO@0SAXLKw2Wh86e3U@KuSV89Ha7kXOlY16fj76LF/4ClrddiDVoxzOvN3nO7cr2Ub@/XtXG7No9C5e42ezgUys3B7tH@2enG6dvjiBXriT5GeP316RtAZHEV2P69km2XWCdsFF9RPoj@9DKwsJtqKxDbSamExGwheZCFS0dVSJrnBniDRNpP5I8nnpXT0UPwsgaFrXYHJE7cNKgn0Igw1bDSs/HKB1KibSCgs7NMoMpPE4gfyGwRPwc2gpNVWU1aGxFGisBzYVW1zZTR72kBb7KJb7m21zLgi2mJ/fmR/Pqzi3Ce5@LfUewEL5q9ebY7m/3gRzT70B1A@Vafa29g9eHO9OJoMxRk@iuvX1srjBx4kzzjR@WkKaFKKL8yIh7hnVoyxKCbhXLGbcsKHu3ehQLUEc232emEYolT8aCQYmtEwd7Ype1HhbJBJUAuRBalitqQuGXWMUKqJco0PobnkVfSKwF/VRy4JnowJzjAxEZvEjq4FYRXPJqXdERFzQ67gbZn8ycsZh1XCNHrp8zi1YqvxVx2XwH1qVpKtwwUZMLGfqBVNYAb6mbl1ChSVsssbXKLbCGyK6wsse9cuLtv2gTJ03Gml06Uy2uAoHq7SpDdCQmIB@bnt6lb0d2nT5XxITn78gs5Iat8NJXcsNTJJRAWCWgcGV6xbh2987qSN3xlkzou/hMTe0cKECIG4VU1zP9Ry0WcpvKnLzdLzJbWEJTS6VJAO5wvKRzyW47NpwDeDeqRO6yOOYQCmxNqLiaFWWzD6wLdMFnqQDyzdwKB4utcCcZOmOEL8opFgsGoMxmfVZxgyLRhDWrc9axoKl9Abkk/ZrnniF4AizG8IZ31hWFGi5SxDaxH2jKhpVJRmgyjxniOeAGvGZJLIIVXIpPa9vhgDn2Ag813MffucPuF3Acw/cPxHuUf4J@H5L@Lrg/m0Zo6rg@@e@rwC@n3Lfqxx22awxNJG90CwsvFAF4/JxdKZOSBOkIVmqi9/b2NNf7h8xt40mSrEv@yCLBd2EFAbHHMjPMP76MCiuqY8RnOcQdGGAJ3H2JQwRGFcwPpC9QY6G8tOdiwSaxKrmclhw1Plm6SyWPuJ7pWQh6@0QLUMCE5ZbLa@W1BwUUrmWCMloxyXeCuEIk8kq0MTItTGovwa5dWNjg0Xdtmbq9dUaHxu5Fe1VMfraL@gKwEa4oHDGIA0kCVJAXEMkS6xoaTWJSXEhi6txpGkdmw814AYT5ACQJAZb8po/sJu2aCoYx5Y@8ohjGksBCAi2ZYdMwkpECiDiuNF@4fR0DK57oBoiNEGz4W6IvkSwEwSrRucN1rNX7Nw7ty6EHUsGA@8Xc4auBe5/Nse4JR9ZaMZk1qpiYtomItaGPT6xbNTm7EFpWaKQKxRz6moyNEKjAhWUF6f6e0AJkxuIRVs33tgDd2t7d/@Lw6OTGes6BBmfBouzeGMjfa5kM2cXviPul3uyUZ/s5U6ePdmTTRkuVaBPQYjgLNx0MeflNl3SBbm/5DdrZvOmiJmM1PxDEdMhE2WPzpDOYg9icyHAbX6wfybXRPL27uxio3FuxWayfz/PYmosm8LBBa5zl@ylxqeLiUX0jcGfojF4NytvjKp4XRQvE3n2VXCZVQSEIji4xAIUIJLNSag5I1YW4JDrZwJ7FgVujd4l0sd1OGTH0i9RCPJU2q3HqRWYXxN2x3qa2zONVgTW7g7a4uNWQ6RZDN/eSNYdmIaXSEZI@1FHDgiIWEJYrx9VR1naJEqQ1VTClWH3mTKT@JIRmASAL340dHvsyB6wQPW0o0vXMTAibGfIdw109sWwD3BdehzrSGJ1YE0USAwNFfeLygVqmFnCktkojdbiIL8ztGcmKp7td8qJUTLb00cd4xIIeCKZgZn@mQoclX@DFytN1s2sONA43sKf44WKcJN@kkG7UYBcO9OyhtXRRwm00FK9ANYUw@M3L6/jyejMGCCretvSDteUeT05ETVPzIjANN3UZFtf9yfZpP3D9XW0coOXkaFbIMcTzzkAJ6xPiW5fG7DEkOw@uizLyJs4T1gZ13OSTGlwYw0WS6dJoIYHRQDDjKBdctHAYQk0k5zI1aF3MNS1Ovh4ZwzYmZrNXoCbMkmyFVSmbcNSjmqoZAQEJEhSJbR17FtWxRLx0ZvlIw/SYHyEDFExNH44J5rMFeLGGsxTaAuqNWs8ChnwCWYgb9X19arojUlSs85gWMxS@WwO0M4hIZJBhfYVd0uh1dCcN9p9d/SOAWTh8fd0y9KhgWDM9DVYg7UhDDInmZGvq8gE5p8phxgv4lNxWRUKOmkWejd@a@J@1UquRnqZ2h2sqa/PcVHtimV1nPuvc9lc7TaxYtbHOWB0ko3ESq@upoupdHrFSiVWLFzqHz1Cdc7dCnASzSxIRyMAUlbMZA3GM3Ae9RWrtqJtJFY69UKKUoAX5LNbSPCNm8vermh3uZVHsFJnIMThkzex4pJlwXw2q95B@XCGrOQyMGZu0RAbvbgCs18x0mksQ3aliQX4Jnd@kiaafX6SI81RTTCiucu@mG5TVNXviZk3dfAGFMGio4GwF5Cwi4PDTQkcGIUuzotbwHvwjL@HdzEYHQzT3TDnH52MeThhEfQuTkafuB1HbtoRGnCUgEZEb0ZLJoGY/O3fxtRVFk2sbK4W7XS8nK/Bj1orszL7bOW8UIqx2GOQ1HOpqBO9Pd9RrpneLay@Vc60bvbtxdHV0dFXyfMEi8e2D19F1RKArrF1@j70s8YKCz7s0z6xWCoXieVS6qO1XO7169fA7sLnrJFthKGyF8kzJX5xllgDT2NtLZVZraQyj@NNLEkyUSgkTxgzjBw7NwZupwNfu0dvjEnE@IdtbmJe4IB/JsL6oy4PCwrDQUSoTCujPgJXvdbKMXa@pmmpdKnw2KplC/nCX/7Z8l3m9qi58Ze/0c/py/g4xMdP7p6h@0Qtf7a8/NmTJ6VSBhqPu49@cPT11tZWaSdTPjorb5aU/PLGX/zH5eVCYaOQW75wXfUifnb1VbSQL0Wzf/lH8aOj7zddF/sPP0WmghN/K/BVWbnMrtg7@Fx1Gf6T@10n5NbQ3eq@wwUSmOU6EZt4vFyMn7yKY3XfxVRVjY3pr0nNsMzUxubaf/nZ4duYF2sUci8deHqxt7HVSow7wQG@ovRdxxqxDQRbvYuNc/V6HZxr/@XfQfrGF4AHY8Yb8NMoS1yr41hDqVOS97HGKjjUQgHy/T9/@MNIrDHCgdDY32OFRiHFx4paeaQ@8vvoPKZWSoePIVh@KHgkPyToqmrhXPZnqLuxa/3gHlQe@pXZoTC/3@XIiDExGsjxUDgod2wXP3/1v//Vz//qZ/T3c/r@B3w5y@ry49c7jOmwAuOnWn3s1y7H1ipR24ZZXgPfgR9@nFXgk21Kfw29iqhZrFLPNHmp/CEcCzmm2sH/ZaJJfP8nwkVich9XOWMXoS6INpA@ybI@s9gz/rEs@Iev9GIIBoDLYkGhZdvGgib1M2fTYbIzfA@TtIB9Clwk9g00/mjOhzWCcEZV4KUmx7NQzYK64XDYhM8y/NE/fHwv/i5TiAgmkNnPMvvun0jsLHZ2cfHUwr/WW/w7eId/bz38O23j3/Fb/Dt9h3/HHv4dufj3rIV/YVoeiSlAGdLpY2AZxaB9yOcFfLPZpvD5gzcWif1aPyzCYrfwuUgrd3dn2VfpWk38AydV83344S4o08Wdomy8aqTTZ1S2s4Yo5IZy0WC8yPSbbb7aALzpjbONur1N32yzAR8lXrLjq/bji1eNs41JHALN48dpnLSPAU9j5YIBD99osLuNu8bd2cbd3cYG/G/Q7514Qujdxsw/PYJPbQGQ/7m7QAJ6fpZrnOfOG/xzAf5sroEh2dw5OBrwbALg2VkkdovDpc7OLsjEUV05U1fLFwqjOZGqYmTbZayqpgrFXHn02epuIRIrRKO5FEa9x5UJ@Iv1SAy59HXOrK9TwOsP3/6v@D3/8O2/AS@UDV94hrERnIfA5axs5s38dV69Uq/AYbA8MJm9fE/tIFXP6yw/zo9Zvm@rHXDp8JcHl5Hvsvwly1t5S1UhEhwey3vo6sLjEv66gMWBPyOfR@T5awa5mLhWkDFWer5vsuR55IxFX@vAnmTVeDYfz67G48ZFeXXwNpqJN8/P4he1WM49P89xxo0VSjWywnt3x5rN3ec7zWYOx/L5M/sw@D887Ie99/73D@1nh3bfhv/Dw8Nn0HPpx2nlMXzqjfSGeGzGGrXN86qCA1IOzVhuY/O8UVTQvZqGYVbAsPQnfgKM8Gwsn0dAqn358qb28iX@31zXbmrk8L3gaNZ8AAHGHRDIAwDBy1qNHOiGzzVhJR86b16e@y7uyL28gaCXDPhs/z834fs1/Bv/7/p/9oIlzi6SMA9u7zYS9EniXzJ5e3d7J34byURCeBIb8IcB4Mckt3cNdBLQLbjOEsmL5N0dD4PfRHKDI2xgHhsNShwAwqyP8VzP48BqgGSYEDta5@ejfD5Za0GIr9vW3tPmSLJGx0ZWWrihBdKQmkoSSLlUq5WEe61Sq1WEW11drdVSPlQePMIJQLqrtWs4m2qxQRLLwOdYIo9KM7J0H49Wo48eJcS7ETYHAxBv1fX8@/d@ULPZMZxmE8OL799Hm1E8OFJfL4M/X3n/HuZ5PAmC73NbbFmugxir5gpBDj3N1TzPSbwzBpkoHoV0o0myRZvPIyimZuWNjdVSo7FaAvdqJZmsRVf4mZPEZXpdTd6t5KK8HiCQxmMiSq2sJSn0Lo7xLLbBNhsw3l38sNu7GDU3K5WTidZYT95CiAxT19d5ICutJirpdfFXX06yRoqJv7Ozs2K6lFpLPb64uJjiWJAm1W61unpXv9WqqC25q7WFWXM87K49elRch9ap5GvnkWZzZ@t0q4lvRMNtYCTNGEjULYJbfAMnfkaqrfL6xRnW6OI8Hq/WHvMerpRZLF4TcEocCCWrrFPFYyA/G1285TIirFPfVGzA1LUiLDGRAR3HWcuzDu5oOszudpchEPqGtXDz2dVNU9qBv7Eds3NjdPTlSOzoYGt79zRT2IDVqrC3tZ0pnLx4ElPRWw78FF1E//Hu1s7hC0hwdLC7dbL7@f6Xuy@OINyNvHmn6bqmD3X9pjkc3rxFU@F6Ux9AaPBp6m3D1d680Qb0YTVO125uPvzixx9@8d98@MOffvjDH3/4w5//8tuf/xi@fwLfn/LnT//tehl/f/ntP//jD//qDyHwP8D338P3z3757e/9kH/J/@fw/U@hsD8X3xAc/7JqrJHCDwyESqGSTsHCkVpfh8FAoRsRyOu3fvntz/7ol9/@9u/D91@K7@/Pfn/nz@Z/f/6jxV9M97M/vh/mp/8Ovv8LxyVhf/qveBg@Z@D/FYf77d//8Lv/G///C/GHzj/88Lt/jj/C89/9/l/8pw@/8X8UCpW/@NcffvzTDz/62Ycf/caHH/3kw4/@aeHD7/1rNR/@@WMYcn/zp7/A/5/96d/8@1/g///8P/7Nn/73f/Nb/xM5/oA7/q9/@W/571//xo//@kf/4q9/49sFvz@@9/fbB4R/@3cQ8vByPgTPQ@r1qSHffqfy/CqtEeQCY4Dsq7MC8HFPxjqI2JE8y4sfmDA//2cffu83YRz@LkCC778FH/xzD0T9hDxffTURlyZBXEl/9RWwtF8JCeerMNBPGHufA54z//g9AHxFsfzDfCjI9H9AKABjAkqCTWROIHjsjwf/8tt/8UcY7qfE0N8M48vL0BDsCgK/l1X8CU48vxph2J/g1P3wix9@@KN/@uEXf/DhF7@FdFsprWe2Mor6Ee0fAJYfAIeAqw@BA0AVpRsQQ5cjBXAsb6C2KqKmX7@GTlgGV52xVKRcBF9EbZBbRTckBKE1xZVEaVQPwXcUKa2DD9VGaVgw0zwqDVFP0vge4XRkVIc4AsUXEDN0NiqoB0D5tw54MRFPk2lWgE1noyeEBVLW08esmaqPeMI0BjQIA8MCYdBxVC1E05X6DmRYH@0wxIXI05HX8Hxdb1Tqowai@4aKADjSTyBLgML3G6dHjW/AXyecAB8Z7XwDRanU0@lGBULqVFXKLdOkPNUyVY7qnmZUbwxnDI/ebT5m7LOoWolyAR2akglo/E0H0Jukp9qE@PN0SlSH/qWTvilMD/00ovbhYTx@E4MpvQAAvIqCJ7bgqyhYmscQPeKo0pQtPNIcA7RcWmj4/ABiJtKRNPVvmjyQP5ThUz4bfCFFdFidlZUVcG00osVo8xCkI@ZcVV1Pc3BTiXi7KouurkcxGE/A8GN9K0ckRKV2UvCrwv/uMh1lpZrUUpGVOArXcSZzUtJFu2THeCVkDcmXogqkCZB9BjH4ffwY3NBC9AzCIrEgHWffaf8Q@O4SS0YS9MKYJEnwOjIsLPLMvXxij4DHzkSjGXUV9wWSXL6PfG1Xq/Vv1NJaBJ7kH@KrasRLU6Cz8IW92Y0NbPTGrUK6BnQCE7caaTTEBihTI42T3VMAPz1kaiGfZcCR35bWCqVyqVworq6W1wpqaXW9tFquFIGUrebLhYK6XiqtV9bX7qguj4EaZKqpVnmj8U9mPv/VP5n3mR@Kn0jjKzbKksL0LtIw6/z83QpuhEbP89EaqTyo5VbO8hn8KxSL8AtlzKjltYvlZfNWwSqf06GvW9xqhmJGbpURKmiX4MMiSxG2BGHwgUxwL4iJ3fv9w5rYqcXXzfHd2qhahsGTjJzD4OHooBdvb29D30hs@Qc/8FijAUy4sr8XicGg7/mvtFeMTraXpZfEdYaOTrGXjO3sf7l/sn/4PLuzfwKM8desUMxnI7G7u7uur1Anr84ODw8pFYg5RRVdd202HA4ptgX@u5EWGYQ/NfhGcGg9ArL5SOXO8mrgzKNzQ1wrbURoL@0MuvUigm/5ObuIbOT8yFO85fscmgcGlMUO8DSpZ7NTm59afKK3F0Bs9/j7qrcdGySL7w7zRLOueNSOwa8V@lFPNTQU6PYNr7cA4sWgjxeBdOfvDMNuvwUFRK06B3gCP45p2/MA1tiLowW1fOZbA8BtazIHAODH@58/PQ09T3e3tp9GVtmTw@c7U4@yACqzg929U9@7xmNl0rKP4uvdg4Npr3gAlaqRKLnMymuZDBB7@MFnhj70zK68kiBq9p7XrKzkYK0F8b6ufqNsNCo1b4W9qD/5Jv182K8U19X1cs3RYRBAzS91kHxtowP1j2meduSs4GWFowOUhOsNzby9Y6W1ajR6dlEbwkSg@cw/jcgzPEe3rvL7IIYbeQryaR/fmYPvx/IieBexg@/FRb1CC19QOxywhYHwwCB0OsZlDwj0jS0BIi1NY/D91A@kD4um0HD3Bng8DwqbiTHngOPmrdFl@UiW9J6F9Uq5sl4sVDKV9UqprK6Wyxm1kFHXKmvrQCzzakVdrZTX1UyltF4sATWH2PL6WiQGRM7o5nKwUqnRKDyrgNZqo/HwDbTCbmd7jUiMa3PYO3zzekzz/UMW1SFNFF845Hp0Sjhl1KOFEh7hL6oMMGqszWJ7e9v5vb1o9Al6UL@7nY9GO@gpV/L5tSfRqE4x27DiFKJRm6eBKADzuCeff7IdjQ45AjRrEI320LO7iix0NGqgZ3trbw/zeYOeAqYHsCsewz2m9KwBmIWeYpF48Gj0rY8O4LZ4RiUq6S56ME@M2eMx2xAXjX4uy5PPA4ZjDscxPJV13dqKRve5Z2sLY76gipd5Ub@Hni36RKMOeGAQRqOX4Lh0dN2KRlvgxKEYjbbB1R5rEIaG2vGau@Vp0eiYNxA2UTQ6ImitfRUFXlGEYzZPnz7Vel5Hv@SfscOfbSgaxBij4e5e6/PPW5eXLWe8tfv5McZ88cVT7c146LQuWyJZqwkfG9JAzFV/PP2BMu43m5o5N@Z7EGNNxTTHTR3L1tTeQpnE5xIz6Te/gJgvIGbehh/HBp8@gLbw86QPzydai2Lkh2LoOWq1ojUcqN54oKPCC@cMvTg709fajl1D/6i@HE/EM@Oz1fxFjYJZP5G8zdfuMLaboJe2IW1M3o7PRvX8BcgPawVxzSARPR8VykY0s9zfBBpXXdY21UIpPaqisUm7G2dxRd1MqI9S7xLPk5uFYqkaPd/cVKJn6sVmQa1UV9depYbRaLKKv5vFteq7RD6eZwx/kmdrF5tr5VCKtbW0litU19aStTtoCQ8WqNbQ05vNROJG166SSSwrMjZQfv5@8DFV0ah1E6PMqM4LxcbJ2qiuAj32hrAw5WdwdfBW/xDfRcQxXgK60Wa@isrGRFRdr0Qh/1wuibQIqQc8X7@UOwn@I@SYcPJPllUV/lI1plZWWTKLp9abdrdJL3lhr8OwyNFGXuLtErpZKk@CEe/vViOnyADTi9gZWhRp4Zsc6T4wyF/cOgXj6gV1bT0SaQgW8Ii/KqEmvGgFILuHr@y1nSy@atKbiOF31GUQOxkDo9DP7h9mX1iu1vWxnOojL/tUx6NebRm2za9/ZndH@K5yw7Zqt8pL5Y6uLeOFUTSKAIuhVm@AS@uwBOXOtOQN1avZaNSb9b7eH3hjEDSoLRp@Ylhd2RPGIfHuiTx@36w/germaxaaB9LRuzKKjSKNDho7eFJ/cjusVgH2rqbX6WXE0Rje19m06kOqz5Hu4FWR/cOVLtPxTka79/p8FwG3oWlv75SGw6yaX4p9l7ePf/qfCnSLBRIRzXr@rnZZP8Pw9/izoUSjF4py9v4i0oBJVRvHtLo7bPGXYeVbIKGs1kYQpq6Vaj3WqrdejWpOfQB8NauZ0FgheYFpNYJ/b8L62Mw266Og2sX6WaFYwJM@mUJ@PVNQYVGExRKg4bsG/hJ8VfhCvIpSRcJMRBmLZvKjfFbNqLqa8exdC1o5X61iY0M3kReeWjJdSJmJjs20DYU6DeZojYqoZXpsYGR6CUh1rGsmB08qCeXt5mq6VEoma2@hdM5KopN9ktws1TqJJ6yZhABY2uFbYKulWreeeJWsJZaTdVd/Wwt3eSIZaeA0pxoPlqFxhajkDvtneba8qmZulaZyZ2qut6KuFapnw5UzRYXq5d9fbkR/0IheQNvfsQj8hfcfgG2oQZic1JzRCFiFIGyAbKOpQ1ep64WaAIkMBIFJRBP4blZ@kjARj68V4vFkvIZC@TKECwJF1CQOpC3@SN2MAqsSrUbXCyCBhQjTTBH4VtQqCEd3kY7hDlhpPRK7jdzd3m2Ez699j43HWlqR3keMXaZXIixH@6rZZowtk0vJNkhzslXfujzeknzm1nYkVqUjP8GxDXYubl0queVP3cxNbzRe8ec5nkSAXCNkzuKMXYjd60IR6twJ@aF@7m2Etyrfn89tpBu580g0SjOVb2VVykleUvZNjIw@s@1b@dbx6jOUb1lCq/IZeHaR/Oa5Yd5WikqDpMAEi32ThhbB00uN3DcxIOl31NDi6NDt7eD2FuTOO2TOC8VyJGbZ8lQRyJYeUDpYC8rlKOopdDY4WX@19qry6tmLwxeHe@xxvlqpVsISwvnjTEaNq/EN9hhYUON4F6SP98wuq99YX9DBqVgtVh3Ei6V4cSJZPTaql@QmZEJtNBR1o8A2YayyKtCbrrqq5N83@MBrUMRqAWI@/Obvl0YbFfAXgM2rQpuW04VGQ00VkrEP3/4bqtSadKmra7GLGM@htJYEN@2hFdRYIyeC1TU1GXMV7oPMyzH3vYgq5CsQtX3IfdFVaJLYeiwSqzx7/Z6xDZDxGp3LS6NArlxuQm5aqYK0BP/sG1TcfKMsvwZC4borOUjP1hFYKhtSjUYjhWpZFm@k8cZYoUxK7rO72gVXBqCAkLLoT3dT@Ke/8gNSrgt@6QNvakNn5YbKQKLI5T785u8VCqv/93/8nfPk@@b75veBXq6vr6@qhdjfzn5yqaUISy1tsTi3k8iXYzSR7N@mi0@8uBUVZ6klZefkcPt7u6e4HusWmgJh24fPsxh1MtDbwXXItqlrjjnmtxC7Y4TCZfx0@4jZDnuxc0RpXtJFWAolBZjIZWW/UxVvaMtcMzVbxB3jci5fyqll4DSq@bVqYZVpQLtcNHwhXCuYlFG1tu3BmEuDie0kJV7aQhiMOzBAXHf1Kvv86IBSEGlILe3sPjtkh88Pvs7KUB5@@nT/hJ0c7p2@3DrehXo82z1h0a0Ttn8SZS/3T58evjhlW8@/ZhB9vPX8dH/3BBHkIkj2kF3lDeZLZmzDHbs55GVdEs8mgl27faV7k@GaM9ByaAd8MtjCN4jp@MKdyfChZYDsF5b8TraWOCvIEL3W6TgRvIFrtNkSSn1LKWAe8AJwL@@usfLwq3d5p7zM2qXn8TXWzj@3ihtrzMyLP2aW@sVjtry8fG5F/UUjXA1f8AwH4WUTCAvKtP@D3aXEaomlQNwslJJBzPPDo6W89C29PD5dUv24452lgu/Z31sq@p5d8JV8397LnaWy73uy9b2l1SDZ8@2lNd@3s7u9VPF9MEiX1gOcz3eW1HxENtY1MHhL9AbfxN7@wS5LAVCyNhGLekh0TAVDQySAJePmULDJWSp107MzJMm0xlPQHf1j0BJ8AmoJucIzbNeLDEvZA/gBfhOAIRndaOEykHPZzgisaDYPVpTIbWQJK7SEFQL4JbyIj3Bsuc4KSQbRS10hKHE7PBkWfeHSddvPXLaBvH4DBkOG7PDRtWtIoYv3j0eW7gTKRJd0tV06zk@gKpQ06kSTSbyr@fzFwQHPbEDMbCJKkIxztnNw2gPABlWEX6w6hPLO4d1CfYFttSQYEXxHeuRuojcj072JTQH1XFpqA4LJ1r3WzAxDViyDxykQL3r4NRwAhmhw58HFL6kmEm2s66XutalASWzM3cM9XkM8kFFnk72cZJgptRRF8ws@798z6Tv3Jr3OpNeKc9wCOS8Wx8dLWkfYJIYtydvBBEGWECjlEo6YdBpSQ3UoLlSvJWh0@HLDCbKUDcgoH2ePHlE5NsC3HqcsMF2acmQKgiAC0WDUfIjML9oyFTe5lEvRfTM8BEWmnHEd4Sa4W2Pf6AtQ1umCTvWqPwv97lyyQBiuTRFkEdXtYF@Du1hogh/JI4zkDGvBNMkwGamuYiSKghmmZ1gXgqdoatOwYOTqTkAT5VCAyUi9/3yH9xC3cEThPIBqDHSvSh0GxOIRTl8a6EtLLUfXrmoSCughQcG4xUGTwIbgcPenO96hZCk@X3BYYuqHpNzfq8pxxFPDcBAjjZoVjVLwsSKqS4GNAGgGv0CG87cO6PmQ5MjSaQHhjzIBtjsJpygc7k6Oy49UYne6FsufXAskywtrsfvAavxqtYBlLRgiUAsg8QnAmwZo@pnszcI8FLAWEgqqzXdDAQtoMJZgjk8geEB6WHKD9Mqnp4dFujo9lWHeQg9yqsCTTHrbk97OpBenL4RobGODFUog0LTQpa6CC40TsAo4OpxWTibsTnpJU1RnukzT9SkwzwHGHJJKDoYDcJYYIwXJuvhuIa2Pb7urs6295v7z3dPJWMSXdZui4D3PtkzKIzkJJgqE8W4CPUm/RIkuNgLnNxNHPI8MtWfz5PR4d@tZBsqXZBvBDJjmAeBHzISJGtzJHCDU0tuwHncyLHGyxVJJ9ghLlmFCwYCeB2dh2q4OqBbm2BkOCpRVnoP4/smZFMMZGZmTVTTBEkn2/vwcltT8GlP7g/fFftFaK3bYuLiGzC7H4/MggspLAvOcT03ObCBkh9uFrc7N7E0@z0pOkXl6DzjuUd6ZxU/1usO1jZZFeRt8YJNQ5tYYGoRE2iIMzsC6OMna3M9F0tqI4wBDcRpDGC7npFtME3@Ow5NiJYPFy9LRP7UsH@NoJ8ui8LJsUKazZRDSa@Q0rEXGjUNhYWPYMg2UQ@mN0mwfVeljaXApw/o2dJqBrrY9oCdqoITaHHyubcIvWQjDHV@y0K2PBqZtoC07tKuDW/JOYDE3Gzm0WB/kXFImc922geboxB11MsXDrf7RHdnIUrs98S7x0CvGX4OUNLAuFRjdXeOSKUq7a2qXLjjMDrleR058eySYg2lo0IKUhXrQ1NR8WcjbZGAYC4dv6T56/jlDI60o20vNkmYa3pjOACOTReeAdTRo7BrXOpAdtNykd7IRLsY@SLQLh6GuajKM7glPCbya6@rOlFQ74Anl8MmlHuMB68epnBg3eOu3qTktw8M3ZTS5ArnJc5SM/GBSoKLTIWLU4YkQPuzohj139rUR@qZSYYuRfizYH0UhAXLU@roUoVKpAaEkZpJxTwhzarAYt9G//HWhnsDdMfQJvDa01RDaimbZDCH6zCXJzQcCukMUaPer/dOmMO/F5SZ/V@oeMTLUyjXpG9R4DULlFyWflTWRbELx0UYIN9MJVb22@ViOkjCHMh/0NvyHREh6JRQWHbENaIk9K11wsShP8ohscD/NIz4SHoVK9Sho0CWxSvhj4IHpuNTJQWbri4i7jq4TAImoUkU@JcH8msfegp5pmZp1ha4al/9ZynXaoc4iw0WheqAc6NdFCIV8XxLqDUl92T4oaNTxu4UAhJQvu/mFhdOZlIiYhvewnzWy5JiHMLrSR3uw7UQQnZJ8BK9bUubE4aeyOgSqbXdRXWA7Y54RGl1I1GoAgswH0QTdkiJ4qNb1oDUQHXEqoVLAuK3JIDyKpgflzLD7S8uzWqbhQGzN/KJyDgehzvxiXfCsFtNCaO9kuDITSYPGkXwROGFp94ATN/WuGHGwjNEY4SL3TKtw9tUfRYy301n@Av7ZZthT5doInFA6qoCQhCRxGqOphqnC@YVG0IY/dTCrYOhRR6FaCrvQoLHIDOAYMJwZ6fREP4WQnxnYbipLU2sn5sQCGfJrJJpetD3BEKMPvcH1C6zL2VLe1pGpJgIJAhU0stTg9Ufjkdz8hiHhv7cHBzgfmXwuiwatSb@chL6bYoJG8anq3ayCkA4A6J5j3wyMkW4mgGA20WzZgEGQ4MMGA@4gCJ8ng2DsbCq7oFfLywlIdUZwucoFe8QS6sZGYk1JUNBnlWTSn4wieSGUPJQYiHSjwRKFVKIoE5cwMaAsTiIozUdQ4AhKqYQqERQEArUMGDiLQUg@A5GMRu0k4koIsY/3YhIGjZ/NyT1VSKsXGxsVFFxDgVOJC/OLniqmC5CYo15KT8ZwtDwiFH4xWSNAXiyE1pEQilK6CCh41unJiCDXqQg/03CepYu5i9OvjXmRyme5@FBytMGsO2cVrC@OVK5pGzBwDzxHBKIdzAFZwwzC@JBO4TAHHoGmJOTW03EnKMOtoYpFC9qvNrUqhjS@BIFkgBpB4jEy7M19a13r0xc7BO6SJRteZxBXM6wCYghQFKAYFUgMJITawLhstvsDHw6W4kqSq7H4AkaZPLfRuvU1cPcdYvtlTkTGePOhYSvAJ6xR0hrC2zcBCZoH@0/w8eXuMaoB9p9/Dl24hPXIsOBXVnOZY/SruK1Z3Ja/4RlQBKBtXKARdeVdNZk/Bsr8BTaJXMBPY@cJqXYIwXhiwR3SuDC8pmELbLwp5TjSPWpHMtjoA1SSNZAz2I3ONBObY8wNzVe4XUfayaPU1FTg8BOKAmILYZudHm89P9k7PH5GLXfU3Do4erqFmEHAbGtOB9APehpOEMvSTb6o@u0ZweX3Et/7gnXSWtJSGX8jDsJyE7a88QCwSTFNCp0uEdaXD/oZeB48LwFRFB8amIpmRx/MwY0CuQ8mKuPOQch7kZdaLIWiTPNWQlrwZldCSUcbSOmoLW3dteIeDGyPzMdZnJ7kJL4nIGWSGVuauchHXdJ4cbjdzmKBjPnjOHKHA9SI6Z1ouPm1dlt36bRZ0PqAUje7lImgLKGGgpD5tQ/oB1e4@2uvwEG2jGnRzft8b8DmTjKLwD3ytvtOPG6IQeJYJI90K9lKYotEzvzdAhOsozHJMi7KjOf2huf2BnLjBJe9mWbIjIuzNxOM2LzmMWTzvOG8seTMOHvi68eo57ow6d0eHgUnXQinOtRh2E10EtIeT9C6R7LLHslZHMzE@czd/UyZaNhJjkwsOMH6KQTmTgeaLTGj2yB1PElfQwf7n3ss/QY9tFLy3RspYhA8jZQmsNMSTpJP3BhaODIQE1BD2gI4E9ld0KLi40sIhEyR5UmGeA3aWhZaAcMCahHsuIm6Eitpu0JQDAUiWRWrsNORk5wgg8XM6UzvUiEQhvJd1EDVyvcmeUYVdJId5DqhxhES8KwUwXlVRYEESa7XIJ4GyC3WgYpnePOrUZmthqic5MkMrtZHUifcKicFCPoe5B4IlZnX5tY7VA@5w4eJk6GK5WtCLSyPKbw4YkW1WAydaTh8@ZytrgZHHvCKCSsV8sE5CrxswlbXI99JTxboE/h4xIkjOhSHFY4ZFN2BF9RNEyYxf3QMXPqxbFwsHvHHuOYzVykuwbqCHIulwWV9fMNKS8c3ieDrvT2mjtRsZAmI4mnoHTVy8QbAy6Hm4Auw@MYxEnKXXodHGVJCemeV4/L319AbXIDi0wsS3aGjcwUwhHTsNr0CBnFQOujpYZ/O/2aQYbjWHTzbZHji9NIS0RwxHDhpaPBBIAMlcWjIscGbUJAEmtGoZOHNSMsyth5XvQhXgdiV04M8lfL0QKUlTVp7xwJQ84qhQm3M3ZEl0cAzywzJ4ylhdVROSR84IP3zVIOziwwXTqUcLtDwNWZW8jcu5ihjaHS1w2vQCFtMoqI6XSTlxh5RALmv05Z6CA5Ej9EFLU@Ei0uj2IL4/heD68IZ0QjiImiVoiXFwVGnta/kDSOKXvLfd0HjuQ6zLwkBlJnYBfT3fAUEDvkkhxAbvtMQOD85xCiMA0rBJ2pKHDckCMThb@Ih@aYRIqVwdCeFXIAIuFxLbBcvP99om18LMUcpU77PNl1SikqG5vJ8MF5lAYa1C4FBoYgepfwzlBzsxVGwmScBqfSkkLqv8BO5PbTwIrsZoImWeGDR/Ya4E7q6eUghcd@@5u@5Ehtnks0M9Q9nkqATxUCgMUvzXqgqRBtIqsBL1wql4DyzTCMpCcWIkwyzJEdA@Y5UQZ5xkATdV3MGhxXmVZSPZFlVWU3qQXrnhGkMaGmcrKuYFuG6KupsZddClZVHJyYqKxLJes4eWrPA0cW3itGhMlxQouI4RvSzToZ91sHNEBESXqNka8yjf5MHOEIT8lU9mJF@/fyy0kkA38Pnqtg7RNIeHu@YDvHm5STHlw7QEqAiuG3V5MtVeKqlJcHOANMzka6QFGpnfzhLFN0u0Gs8DEeXhQ8KElMwYghLnX3D8dASRK8oCwFLsPdE57EASR8WX7wShg2NIkGZJyapHB0YkU6L9aw@oQ0OToUsHIhhLIJ2hs5d3JueaMpsKcYYx5fJ@ThkErHcB/O/Fi7IeGFBsDloj0isdf6eET/ndfer7owGvNtAcG7Adw0K8PNWMGKCfyvnJR@QGAT8gi8dcHkgzBsIRlsyg6jYwjcBJgb8vEeGQe4L4YNjk2/5Bl@752BKOtYYTkbn58IEiZewEBKLBiEhZraY1DvUogPeJ5Plpo4kRYiPnVfj0eAMkeUKCm4DcmdananVBDpGJzdIG1fjJxqJlcUrNCSnho80YsensPK4ZRnIWQM88SBPOxAKoz8wdf5eQvWguXW4H7ylUrylRXdtDHKztnOZuzGujBwHjJyIs/iKPsR5jifveUxz9wUsZXiK3suyE50fVtDF2whfkzipD5OvMREe67cAuNsFjtfClwbJl1gJBG42XFiI1lz@Vs@xbbeC0mv4tmGQSXkBMlR2Fwp/CQ0zbNErZdqa5@pjPYcJcy0TfvoaXu3PgUiewxrmDi39AFKf4Dsfs2@0ay2yEyoYvcZpKle6VRNRUHdEMfi6YX56BHUIHr2opWVD38DM1emkhBAS6HKebZljZuG5pkt6gTOjVxfId1Xiyw7xpT1iU4eOPPB3RJby66tE7F2xwlE6XL@zWYgrJyPcxn2ViRcp1mA0o6zDk0@caZk6k8En5uQhCi7nT4a18cbBx89p@Ec8crlQWtt6yLmPeWc86FIDNPuikx@5HKpHBya@6PBGI6MKbLu0ll@tMv5GVRqGOFvoTRQBx66PBmgpHg8G4Dou05r6tW6yInbjl4Y7BMATbwhVisQGjnbZ1yRgolhlmE3o4gHJ1xPHlIIo2zYnQ7oaLhiBRE3vpmJqgI3eZydWFWxMESzWBT0JVAt@Nlmzadn2gFXB0cEXSdJigK8GkSnQjr2WaWECLdlItJKb8KzCE4pOl/ZhHuPkr/uH8vE8kW2wM5jmF0xuUERrEaoFTP06L31NpseVA8FCOzqwYPNdDVgRUqwphFGuJQBoXMMSHM7lek/aPJcgHXv/ELU2lCHM2EHCj8Eq8itWydrCMyUpFjpTAiQBD9HjwKRz/bmc1IzEt9Dmv/Q8ifNY0holuDtQEfFVL@U3hzy/0OWnTzboogOj24zUnEmcgZRYrbE7CYhnQJDDwZMlSlyeHEAO08G9meBECjR9VEph96ENFaD4EUjqOBxmuC6FqkGZ0qbjnX9uZTpavZB7WBBez9dka/BXhPj9H2xmPeK9uUQVX6YXjtwyeVm@zTdiaJdEbDBNlBUXLzFGaHRwXGKJT/DxQAGTo0FoE0lpmvEVqrygXOcKxAJ5ToWWlAwbsUvUvnPxKcPGwotWQiLcJkA@M66rNd9wgG4N@7cojGR4kuEgg8B3TAdqX4vgr5DoHJ65P7thlSCyjoScXnJHQWcyHFUbt/kMU@9qlHObTGpyEg98xOzYn3sW69xCfNUzEEXo/4IvE9XPOtEMzw@3DMihSkfhIhPkxhvRL/VobF8lRpkxkA6WGNHpTpI60C2U8@Qdh6Lo4KXYpxEEBvWwTQ33HZvYdgl5rYI1R3UQkJrjOurw@KUGZHj5tKBTsQhfZQCoKAgIEiqTzC7FUzMD6Rul0xgPQt1k/HBAF2Nl@pl47D3Cz9OH8d8FN3@oHZqjTHOclOdSIEVznKIm8I@n3M1Ul4r3K9R3prxT9Z1pD7@@C9rDr@9se36n@voa46@oIrDE0ANlHBTZN0GixlcMyUCup9hkGJgPVqidr6dTDwdoyW4qNVnvmU1tDwa2iyYk5peA5zmnEBQfCoc8N3keVXCDgJzj6iO1koephwZZ3Aif4o6N/GKC3GjhmK9fwE@aXLct1mgKQMzrpNH3vcqUHzJIiqUkHCRJol8/zIrTVM5OANt2ReeL6yyUVc0vOFWUy2CMEvu1TzLuDeEIVZ2OL0JpZBJsqCSbl2SIfAemm06CYfOTiFYX9HEyFbY6m5tKdiKmFqcrJSdEZCe6z6WkgOuOhvaamkSdYbiG@AlfjvX1vaO0HOC8M0jTG0/LVRpEsX3@@vFt8ZreI6Gdwvfs0ovFHXt42WN4@h15QP4mXEzQtZG7R@4SuHo0bD2E4dOpymNxiaD6vv44x14MGAj5@/L978@O2DYy/i16gTvXBSRCy4Q4YbW0JHmnpUClvUSU3ge@4Io@rnEIsqc@CxVgB8cDFOEZauIg@2MaTnMylouYovocSFTzPLRVgpy1eIU9Vj9INsBtmCAhcgDy4gIxK0s@6PzC8mEcKi2VLlzcAxgq80qbn1tIupMwXciWjqq@/D2F41rEad0NFAdzx9Ls6H8H/efnynevQe7/yNCETOWozBCcDkIuHo4GZgfv5vfRWju@e5iPVJDAAeVzfEuwaY4zczHfoD6OZpd2A7IXicoIl86K4vRAnr3Gg0ZzU9OOW0@DrqKrA4gISkCslXwrI@Kht3azZySO@om5AOwSK4eXaXkx7DbuMsvEsy2BBhn1jossq4ZjhcqZwOsNYrrKXcKOgW@Bw5r7pFcWh/TRJC32jDa/lbF9hEVx9LdDw@HCNpYmC31J535gKGz3dHxnKsCiYbkAu2JYCjSb5Sl2l7lvh5qDKgfbYem4GxE0nq80x@IkzjQfJQhUbQKYRl59lgkJASP7iffbpoaV1NehqkbSPDqsg6aM4q6wLyR0Rti2Yd0Pak2yDOiVr5CB5dnktBhaiPCExO8M6w5NpMX2IItxSAknKxv2IWPZWq7zm1kT1Qx5JoA4YZ2MDWEUx1AcH0OClnGxEnNK83Hw9RlozGoBsMKhfRkr1L5@o0FTTrTbxPYOXQoK9BcQTfrzBI43V8J08ayFowsRAtPkkxnKZBYtLcWzWC3bUsKYOdgsYoBDsORD@6/@99R/DBkgC2kPEJjBAF/jKt@lTkUX0ifMdKolDmRRFaAD/aHpaZZuD11z/Hc9ECJLZAxa8M4QNCbv18I7yY6jGMalsxxaOGH7uUM67oZnE1BQB@JdOKhiTPRUkBrsuL4t1llmimswbkYaRsNtosQpxh2IOFwc5ZmAqRhYnRhqevCYgEd3vDL82ACQTrouZnlZSicP2Gltb0hEtGfj4Qr@ht0MHnXoAxmBcOoSJNhYF0RuD3SHZwajbWwPmVyfPTt0fxEIZHCB0IBMxdJH@JE2Y7Vw3POFBPAg7hAq/s7xUBogv1BwAA/edM@Xt5YudBS4uPHdLXpjLORA2cITcRv8DlyQ4XfOje/Coc4Xs0TcU@ny2SiZhglpyfg5@8SykO@TUtCfOv9ELLPUdUlYPqDE2X7cSaBTFbNqOSnAGjU6aJEw6nhSYwNvWMC8BNAz42K5jnst/NQG6c6wF29ggOia0@5BlaC/DBwwnkPt1DE61Gwgw6Ha27fP4DJAj4bdkpyBtob9lo4vHaH28q9p0r4HKskBJBGgTlLOwdVLgyickYbxfI5HPUl/3En6c4tnRXIJCj8A6OuRcAUVZSL9pWgY9Acnm/zW6SaEF1UhBWwW9J@JQEW9kEY2ZqIKF9Ichy/yFWrTGNV7MCYD5dnUlTBUeHmhI043tnPFd45Q7UaU39MM0nvjXiA/sIyJpEYPN/ndII7vZEjlXGCrieYzLiw9zfu4kleOJg@Ioskv9PCLU0ED8z28WnBo2T@NnOdjC0hYm2ugciIKT0bxtHznkhN2f/DIPVeuQ@R3g/Lhq1uirevhqcD7Wqgy@b02x@wK7mpibAhIMSIQWpYc1e9CJSnzUAgNQfHCcxmHCp@uS7CauO6khEPuUPzn5ZTNJ8aKbjXycjby8VGv89ER5OEfEm6Hjuqm5PUGfp5sovmxyuO6b5Xmu7UbUQyuTq2xkTjfRTetRvyE19KU/M14jc@QJV1aGn9K61Bb@MfEA518lEazmAYkd/iHAQt8bExJeZIwdvnUn3NVRRzy5DZcYHlnaCFGXN8Ab1gZ7npJf7teTFDXy7oejZ3QSq9w6gPje96800zXhkWSc2rmWMx6l/YLP20nRs5Anr2Yd61hF4uCO/2QJrigMns7Zbnrkxw6mss3/HlLETidOxwiDj7/k6HTgtJKCL@1AlB0ZUXs8IuEZ1InjujFMequ0JHxGrBUU2Qr6iDKQ5WgDe/9wPQcSVWfO/olPI4NLFHHjSO/5O98ZyM7XJl4dLj//HT3uHm8@@Xu8ckupaSD/P6F4uEgR5oy9wYtFlgCb9wN27rLRl46BqzjuOKQ8TiUwE/atuexPRB3dRDHrzRIqQ31yMI998LB4rgXru5UefpTzszT5Xs6aewaeEVoiEeVoH43XADn28MJN8kHP6yBeMMfhX7kiKWxuwjSTCDmPAbpJ86klk3GWwlC3GzAJcXuejfIAQppYnKP2X8PWFacsZXQqHII7CX4BhGQAYB4PHU7ztLLLcJzFRpeB54T2UgsK7f7DrL3dp4d8Wx3KFu2w@uFPKRm2tZlRFhPCJWAODdYtDL46oyqbGK6FARZ4LkFmDrU0rxGvEI5lA9yajaf@/WZNAg2sf@BrBV8hyv53/Ge9@w9/blG4eZd25eGTUI8zt3UHboJW3Bzb9DNN0E3eaFuKqOCyOi7XSdffJtcoC/@A98gX3CBXJSu9PdzafzXe5/7wdesf2UbC3//13DmDuCJWzly@M49Ynr367uw8/@VWyOfdl3kY7co/vHqxPyrE8JK5Kdcnoin4nT6GDmP/UOusEdVk6/@ceXpbmGjbYonk1Rr4qCtb5Zr8tB8YGRLnER@2CH6iRP0E8fK/86Owy@u65y7AEF15x87/oRahy5HTFQ0/0kn4X3rYx854h4@rX83UX6Zb/jYPh5pd8bIewaKNJxzoriTR6SJ2rx/zyaOgfObLvyMLw1/ccLcv94izr2HlXHyMLpYO6TOjKecOv7OlYJzUvuWKz1h@I/bDJy0mylGa/hOooDL1yYOxAs5Kilx3c2239Sx9aAFA2UpGRELK/FFWRMpbBu0rkdrA949SE730QTKQBm7COVk18i@WJSZmGgzd0L8Hfj/v9y28ocgv@Dxj5es/gEvWf3jrZF/vDXyj7dG7rs1ElvODV0n1zKsHLBmJlNugPund5ruHLKXT7dO2enTXbb3Yvt77OvDF@zl1vNTfK3o0YsnB/vbDL67z092mf8SVPp8qTt45J5B1@/obZ2084V8vsQI88xbF0rsROuzp3Zbv4bBs@Fq/cc97slautfgqXavdWds8@2gAR5m8cStCdIV8b0mqXHCG9ctGMl93EeUtjyxjGTN05VvFITJRu948C9w87094kHoHBdtK/mXNgDehlBAo/EtWTo7jVvrxLR0skw0nP/55BYEpvDZCdt6voPmi3f2T/cPn5@wvcNj8B59jWZ22M4@mo158gKjCPDZ4c7@3v72FgXwAuSzDHVrdGH9viJkEZxapX3VHbavsgMTpULhm3itRywSsWx5K8Jl8aEVmO/pwJDCfXdu7BQVTjCwV7aOP/8SuRr9LYtG0XIvNgh/o4q8gbCSx0sjkJt4NUCNYIi1VFROkPpjtoLRNXqla4LcGSaRJ2mf2NBZdBvViLghzd/8SgybRA0ZLQNuRCUNwdbZG2CQE/F4ZoNQNiA30h7I3FCx2pUeTPpYGGZFOTImrbS6hBQtzu5bbW4bXAbAuOenuilbz@EAqBASARwAdTAY4GlX@j4qSVhZQAw9FPwhYJUHvOkP9m6Qa8QLriLgCXJCZAgi1IvUpRprOZph8X6cuNbEqYPmtg2DkrgEj0ZyTFOqXOlIHPD/Yo8Nd2UBMgpUsAszWwoVwbYbjAag7T2t67ksUU@iNhhEEN0y@EmtS1MDcY/0wg5eWLrGYwSUbQXfpF0Xb3MKGE6yLixFmNaYTZbDT7fz/7T3ZMttJMk9C1/RamqEbgFoECApkQSbog7OjhySKFOUdyIoDAZHg2wJRMPohgSIwoTXt8MOR6x3POsd7xE@dtdhv9qOXW@E/eD3mX/YL9g/GOdRVV3d6AY5R@yT8UACVVmZWVVZWZl1ZImJ37tsOSh5d4EintujSuOBqTZbuxcycHeBga@CBhBVdH2BYYVGEb9dimiCvhBlKwxAIsHlMz7S4UGce5OulyggfB3rhf/mjS0auRwX0Y74EHfqhN2LydkIN0JeYwwqCnMBTgydlDzF3SjuQytZg3hv@AwPQ4yRwQ/d3QQ13XmQFMVJHEEU7fkcqp02XYa7kCpJPJ8NVuprpGJG0fZ3yNfyaJukg26y8uZCjOeMhxgwstMYw7z0DTxYNIuIE7S8tguFWHd8ZITV4w823d37d59XPvqw3KxWT1gttHu8ecGHEnmbhVxyGB7q7CSdBpQjTSAthJMOlpbnGVlb4iiXyMBwOfXB@N5rNVQeL6supuObdel0Snz71uVSFbpvQiI0CU@tWLuVjWNJskxlmoYtEMS6E5jFyLoypUw4lb7ew8c6sBca0CJD1CN0vEarLZ@v0aJd44YeaJaCsNO4uxV@Wz6wICSKPpbeH9UPrLtuadeuSigaTKo5LamiyxJzzRa1oodKaL5aQHd/OTrQ35dHt7mUO54evhS2@0uxfSneKqV8XDwtabguj/ajJWh5cvtKaKHu5XzEPEkuYlOSroSzfG1FyvwFFD9c6Dsae4AG595RMIqRatQmwwFGiLN4URxYowK2jiY2iJ4e3d8/PDRMenVzG8qC3sP3H3tCDSLuqzLSEd9DJmXnKKNJfmLjSaaIp3iSZJcN5szGy1EVwgYpi/ZQyiJ@KrzvT8XtCJ5ZyITAi9esEGXLJbk7lzooPBaI58d4EsqIO02rYCGzmis8@XCQfVIycbuV2TYOX/ojZcx4UxGsi5aqxzMdkTSEcTpon@DOd3b/fZvt421Jhw0s7/cnVGE8hN/FePnGUyA8wp1iJ9mDS7pFdimdWSEpXZFtR9fykhb21xco9cDEXNjCmloXxrFgje3ja9LMoWVNnAZwn38mMrtnYr1TqnhK2dE71I4nPSs5BYGRCW6wsadLBRRvzsUURq2h5klXGeT6WLtG3BxLLpt4xkjgbuQDvQMW/MbNtHpIkwJtu5RU5ZshxbNEgpJs88zKyEzAfHNjY@0i3OlayOKVr4ub55C0/ozORq/aGspwFtJRIZDcB4/LMj8WgCVN54IX2LPkgEkVBFMnY05J1J0mI50/4IWfqwZmDp4dlXG9KE3VNqYp3rKx84ykYyeQhTpoQ1hVlEfNQuvPl5NDhXwhvatfnh4PNgTC9fD5F/wK7WEwQlWJb4q3OCoquOTbIZ6Ki7AEv8SuIv1yhD3CtBdG7L4eN/k373DjHWmmuBcFL/FcvytKOeFoAErJxG0o56w9On@LC1xvacmU8/BOgCjrl429F3xGZZVTegEdIqCgBoIB4jKZBmr@VUvdL4S8bTw@WOBXPhFA28B0VQMWrxcN8Hu2cVWhLNNKnAb2iUqqcJJ8/Fql3@B0vJfgjwYzlV7l9J73yscw2SJ1R2B53R6ptF0BOYF2wDNfKsMUwLRW6/dnLWp2lX2bs8GMUUnvCGbAtxwEKvUqp@KZKpl0LMpO4qQmJ4EnpZJWBBROTH6ky1LoeS9b1MkGTwuAsFg2hv6g6YjzU7ct4Tva4gpHxB0J5b1hr0CdgiIWo5JTwh6GlhUidLznNx06QCkUEPpkccfyQNrz4wI6MKSDfq3JXyRUXIwYwL@CCcGqLrxI@XjvBUr42Au7E89QT8MnpJICg6zg@1DGwbvG4cGT/SRq5LiFNgqVkgf2UASPBWNUHTlky9DhwSQ6bXGi/JnOfe1xrkTBvxXQMBhrQPwznSsJEIomDkvj/G3vrXEMk/dIdYrVs5ui02WNVR2cbjAZRudvp2@pe6dg6TkgAreNuYOLBLcXmkWMRGFhS3Ggvbj2mddCu7IlwyrEVCiFqExFbI5A3LhOjXl7XpCv@kr9CV0HI5OUtNKKGCUCNUGAJs/2GBcMQg@ao3uqQMa0l@3iK58pxnBScpyF5JJxy7ZFcU@qpEVilyRSyiOyFRNhCVN4nBBSrJiabfQC463/Nn4bXU4qOPVvpr0d1doYu1l0ozbF0LBLwKw2tWzeldDq3Cskvy0MONGD8X3wQoxHDAjoPU2buyzjCTCS7wUwpRwkGA@gBTgaBQlAHiYLgFR@EWMrm8t46GUUyeY4Ho@L7ORQidFlFMmmEjOd7Ip4rKd6oxuAdcYPkuCXFjiC2vya2XMgNguE8warkS4oRJHcmRbTtPifnUFDqmmGAHlsyq@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@VNZdXnn0jjYEczCUb00DpTAxTY1V84BwZz/mlmilmgPvBYlUtvlTlI0FM524lcnXRfpqhp4X5AwJOCnqV9ZfAjDXJf1geYGXao90OlYbA/L55G0C1Mxae5VXmCuYUl7Ybywc0upvAKrjbyGcS2MejAROP2BGt8Zgz/loqcWSQRCWvdAJ8bpno7BRcLedIT3IQ0Qwgn8t1p4NKvVopWhJ4cH3zq886j1@M4jdKJWWEfh8g2elqHjOqtO3YQsXm1p0Zki18CjFliNAulhLY/4E2j2aRahl2Ox1Mq5Bjc32YBCSi6tFzlD77XxLmQ5tDOYxomQjlqbge6xiAel1M3KK9OOIfUZTNZK@Gu7wAnBsJwITghGSy5ozhaXfz7kEyrPh88jBuwYx3wnM2zq/D7Hi0taQcOovHoe/Z437uBZkooKWsq9iEfw0Xej4FR45EKsoMcYtA78olo17sqguOL@WnvQxZC3kz4Fvj3zB@2zTq/tjE5HhX7oivA0VrEfYpDLAh6menC0f/i09QTf6dq/Rzcn8NOgvKMHj/YPnh1hzlPIWhPJ@4eHB4ctOqB@@OzJEUYMTSWZOqDAEoOJhATQ44P37jzUYPi3KZjkCyEh@JvwT4TyKRv@qDWlvzO65lHmoxAteoSHrqlgUUorG5F/5gUT@Xgbxp@QE3wZb57gpgzQkq8aU0AaC5c/RV4c63SuQREf48koIlA6AW@lWsJOlmCYs/AEC1AsohDsdjpN7/CKMubhRb5gZKXK4gUZLFYQ97v6IY0OHCZPZ8OuJdGJQJ7lc28IkLjbVJxE/cpmcW5jVMkRHRpKFy5WYeaoUnDUYnZJ0YLiVHpBe8RIX3ZtFOSFd4CiGyXUCfHNFCrAO4gNo1Ty7fOC/kCUyAKtyu9HnRvaHfokjHi/5orWRxzWlM/5An0UEPVN3MBRMsI/n@ibUiRgYn@KLnMc481z1Wb0X1aWV5gt1TtWyI/Py3vdDp4euQcM34ksDvRCMftiuRPbXYKBFmakezyZB@jF3pioMBFkGQ@jBjRUNJ4ZfIMwjFRzQc2b@HcqQrt28QCNBQJn67CmybkcjhIvCYURA5CbZ@6a23EYG76WoA4OM8SODlHLgvhAh6hnQbzSIdayID77mEH8vlUqyc7bNeobG3yaOdGfGcX/XRWvVCTsjjwKHRcGfHpxORszkn3GIaBLLl4H1edsQK5zdnMpZ0nUn/0H4NZxiVIVIsKML2F7CebP/9Dc5hW6S7TS33ENNQWFxonY8uIrzLheeE@IuGRJ3CVNY/vFEmymKXsxu@wPYon4IEdoPvtlAiZbbD6R/W6o9pM7XFfisrX4VkMawX8uInC/DIIWl5fji6KN8gVezK5vKyyyBjECBlnTQeppkCySb5eSXNXx1TJJ1nSQ1cuQ/OxXgqaYvzIgfqwgSNeKxswE/e/EQKOj@VAoCzRkSLxT8yTe9c0FP0nyoBfLAn8SY6cizeV8f/6dNN9xyUz4P8oUTiqgy5fs9syG/6fL4ljLxfEho6hUctutyBClUi7EZz@N@eDmTQ@zZYPk8z@5uPRqfuk/iEvH0/yunLjZapDI0ipQHQ9KZlLRY4WN@w8aQKVkcKNNo2rMaUMO52JxYSxZgZrKFjfOktl1mT3LzF5T2SnkczawpJWE8fXIMNrhFwbJNIq/0y1fNrhk5q6rW202V0i3dtlYFxfMoW2UjSOu4mhGz27K4biRcDIWUYtcWxh78wJZwY1M5ydsj9unwzY@0BoGQ0e8AOIH1f2z4IWPE9W4imEunBdhnjf0dUxrQkB@nIvu6x08UAGsiqAifPab/XYEbHe7k7PJAPfQXOFXYWCkahVDxpEjOJychQInzrh3J/4AauCipRabiODmjYBLmoXBlL4U@RTpLLKLJKtVPjfuUBg6SiLeumN/FBExd9EXwJBPZKACCX9Hg5UmPF5QPydEHIrWFfV56A89S4PHV1z9spZAcRFKLpdqkGSk20TDUcYTII8nZwkM56LH6WyMyzlOiDd@rNVyHVvOQ7kxxh6@EKJuR/ihURcx6Ci0DCIRN4jGSSz18rrNrUSInoB4niUh1sv1VSQ0wiwKUUSRodXJ8nafwhbRpVbCQdgUNPUCWIQxetGuu6tQO8hQfLnmb37y8T@Y9nm1KtPoTR1/2AafgV4kibHiz6PgifytoUf/RNxVTOH@xxg3o@55Xf@sjS/URBpqEK4czNCBiPkcBA2DVgUD0DfBiaXFgpEEUbCq1Tv37xtH7x0efBtvQ/EiAklBqjgKwbZhlrjZqWQiXxwMRhAhCYswjwRhBJJMLEKpWiGYqjGF1@lb2gksaK3v/hm1Fq3lB3jSncdlCiFmmxzUB9cJ8WytjlZ1hJRg7Ifv/iljDkZ8ejYbcTAyhWDC15EHwi@XIq2FejFENr1f//AviZy4UQI2H66rnOmk84x@yj0WC7Iks5VaM7dWCTLUCLmIL2yi7/2MkIX8SLdUhIUrulZUSLKr/eO/NQgHbj5A72kljQSe0oWIPmFEaveAWi4XX@VCfN9nfD2fdgF0RJ1ZsoqPYJ50xnhpyNKSqxc0369/KDgGeD/CPZMlNG4k2C1kdsa/6T1LZUV35PWvhj@3h3@kIxXXXPMw8kSViefjX8XDVK8mh05m@b6ijc4Ua5kV/vi/sqSPzpjD6MEI4IxW76rMsZLD81//jcI/LVyZXiAwv/nJpz@N6zjNrdk0tz6fxqNpuliLaR7vV1Iq6X2cMszSNLcrfpkkkxi5U1f7mYfgF3ntPk029jRvyIPoq0E/vWDY5yH5RCJRA3564ZDPw/V9iStzsKerlTPcp7nDXGLPGegp/Ddy2ITB@K/6YJwu6/ncMZ8vFn9PyNHgw8ujC91SrQoLZ5VM2x2jRv8xMi/@301zo2s/XGqLDRcXLCpAh15TQvYQarqjj/zz9Jvyc7Zr4tSaCLYga6RRqQkq4Jq0B2EGKdf9xmjVsenA3cugsvvViBTm1erQ40v3k1EPvQ7avzsjz2NM23/4eEC2ZvwO9SVY2@Cu8G0bCk9wTCw3aQcnXBAfREcxh6SrgRGge@Bu0P8dVd1KjVPI37iSxjII2CS6Qsvp6ArlOiLCkyjVmplOBfupmQPh50oDsXfVYe8KG0vUkeLIxjkXKu/v/VRpJNVKQRJ7CmXpYpz/LLqBjhjRXjlF7BA2XT5qN/FLOVLJVDkF5E7d/6JrixS5fFtSA8vD/IM/VxOdF@JZ1h7UB6@8UsR/fBwTGyZ3BtT0J38lBJZ9I1YZuZT/QnZ8yBoqjzjOZJegk0PmZ39somhnNxJnNy52sgTGXB/LePDYePZ0/9A4eHb05NkRLsjogRGVD57v6LHbzXqZHNjkIsGCL9sAN7/O7qyWx@Lll/1S3abq/9WnWH1GW3LNVVNrpqXlfpQoV5PllrQRdcWlW0i0z0J5XrQA7pi2qK3rbooWAgf6wTDC8Rp68EWA8cIEB3wWcxuLP1@Z1r1uQZjxXKLrv8lqaYsx@YsJONVhB7g1A/vPXf1/yfjtSAYtWc1w987N2s1j/FALGfKTQH/bEpRY2WwUvvhixRjNotNgWC@sGGr91aD1V4wZxKucL0Jeww2H/mjkRfQUgXHiDXEBGh9n8wO0KjBAB8a@h@8vPboDvC2RG7xc2noRthBRSyByRjPDvLZnFgr@2SgYR8abgd@R3/Ed0Zvr8lc4CzHUQ@h5WY9RH41nD6KDIdoOVYxqGAX8XX@XGsMthdDkAOEHzngyrFJICG/Yw6VrOirYfgmsnQI5qFqvBWAtrJZl4@5x6GEIKfP5tN836YK1N@g99bBx0cIzVLTzB3iZzwTmT008YbZiPA4ib5uvRMt7xiqSBrW4ZxTFglllwG8u0qp@UXuNA0@l4XtTtHti4sElsaZO4XlMhxaJoZRp0xK7hee0@kEQxfDyuIUowJs3iRJYR3xIh4UX4/7GNcJnvDw8/SmYKBmGSCA@4p@CaJxAhIgb0Djl9hgHjrpXA0bgTKz/17YxBBfas2Cub8vzxz6eZa5tbmP8bKoJNih2k1i@rW1izoQfXMdXYfj@uF6Pkis4AUDuEHqsCMYBvlAddF7QQQ80qMHDRvlzZB6aEB0MWzKgOOxoY6qnxV93fA7X3vNDAsCS1ZM3/kg0UTkhqp3JSejwWKDo534YTryNW5vrxBC9PSBBe0E3AVqvAmYM/1Yl5k6js4GqxVZ0Kt7UphgtZ/LRbYqUBYOS5AxjIbTxXB4I4E2bRAeaMlFTaAVrq8xp9/fffXjnaP9@2ajUNhCcL5EoWEtrXM4uUT4dshRihEV4@Dqdm@ss5FZYLu5Vi7ZgfU9v9pLOsEQA5tYYde3IKrpUTFjPjBjUWg91VVm9iaTeX8HzVDjckJXJGCMLm7Jx5chfWTFRpJHWCopgwq6DMnZBXT2BX6B4FoBydQW0gNBuLXR5MNw/Sa65c7VSUWNqm75VQLFWKrt8F8y8B3PlS6N4OBkmtG2Rxk7bKIKSw4g2rNquFkkvOGbDOHWL74TFRhfmc2UgvLIm9rl8hmfYRy4sbrij4O5M9p81kTtL0CD2ca1p2yKh@L//U7Qb8/jo3sCK7HOc4t64Mmybw0p9n6NcWUX22KDYGycCR/MeKdfIjRqqQCfozRx6Nqx37xQcC@uNTmNk2ed0Aqnrumv2OZAcj/Cs6AiUoXcEGO0GpvUTafAD2hhsjOrz50MMXXcD9@nef/TwPejyQ4wBEUbHHzRvXKuWi0XwJmiX0MVo3Mb9g0dPcLYf2w7N@u/CdC3aZdxWRBxcfMfbPcR92cSqVXEUguY88SJR@/Du7Kh98hjMMavYhiZIGlltfWcOn6LF83Z6G7lmsnPBRjpxCep07PUbvOk8D91X1ondiODfqU5iA0i49Tphj6CQi5f8Uq3uD2G2fu/o0UO3uNM2EKubMSqKpY4SDhAUEhgLk8gPT4gOPnmHUhXx3QoSGPiUiuZusi471fZusTGf5/LzMGj3OCpHMRbgnjUpC4kbu4td2hjHUjAbeS4m8NT2rf0jswxlxxPPxkR6h2BGSosDBrqSBosbagqaAmdPEcZ1169fpzQsMgldt766auMWzhyw0T1NQMsDa9yYj9tuz1IN2R75Drm33pRpkXFSd@rV9jB87Y3Dau1mfXXj1u1gjL59zwu710NQIW4bn33zo9l1vGxHW74nwaB/ve8PcFHp6vqNzQP/7u@@v/X05n2r2/mdmlk2X4T0Du94pDMwbr8WO/SgY8ddli5iYgg4u@3qqP0yqK73Vrubq5u1Wz3v1oa3ubq22d3w1rY6W1tb3f76Zqe3dat9a6PbqWJoRyrinNEGv8nij2T7lyObZ5ht1le3@v1a7eat3sZWf6u@ura23tnc6K2ur/c3a@21tZu9@mZnq7Pcaov5KYCClXoX5460Bn4n37grLOh2Udr@Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
#xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/=>+&&1=1~-<>8;t$ U=B~+Num839195;reharngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$say PLcons=>al{} 47:""[];u 23x;         >
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write( 186 ). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Main code is on lines 125-133:

```
!ZZt
xxxh
xxxg
}}}f
}}}e
xxxd
xx}c
}}}b
x}xa
```

It is based on Hello World example, ors are replaced with xors for Prelude.

Curly braces are balanced for Japt. They are separated in bunches of 3 for Pugs. For some reason, CoffeeScript
requires a space between `#` and `{` on line 124.

Chip has non-nesting block comments delimited by `:` and `;`.

The rest of the code is fixed in Chip by:

- inserting `:` in some places, which hides everything until next `;`
- adding spaces around `!` and `?`, which stops propagating the signal

Added `:` on lines 2, 13, 23 (`":"&&` in Ruby), 34, 38, 180, 217, 224.

Added space before `f?n` on line 194 (`O` on line 192 and `;` on line 195 were moved accordingly for LMBM).
Added space before `!` on lines 196, 208.

As it turns out, old Pyret code works only in online REPL, but not in command line. Updated the code to work also in command line: `208` → `print(208)`.

Answer (score 4):

## 238. [a-gram](https://esolangs.org/wiki/a-gram), 11076 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNZdhj4mfD@g/1yCbALSAAJIEGCBAECLBYfXexhFTkkq6t7SDYqASSILCYyUZkJEigWO0bjjVmNpfDK41nHSFqrR7LlldaOsGJjNyyHpXCE9NWh8G8o@cuGYkPzD7TnnHtvZuLFYvWMpN0NgQTyPs4993Xuueec@8im7nX/5m8S@GFHjjW6tByf@Ybns7ZrXhtujj0Zsce66ZWKy7EYQm25l4OeYfteJZZgGmO2ccP27ZbZhjDmO1eGbb41XIgrMtZ3nUtX7zG/q/vgMSEV2zGsd713Pms5vZ5utz2AXGbsSIfIzqB1xfSm57t6yzcdG6JWGHthW3qv2dYZQBhu3zV8Ql9ibMPo9f1RHTyrjD1zXM/AHFuG5zkIsRaFKAOE7prOwdbzTycwrTP2qQ6F6VvGcCJ7rcBemobbnkihaezz0729ydAi@47q2GwPqzERtcxeuJ5u6ZP4V9jWwHf2/cnwEtu6NGydFXPrueJk5Cp74upTSdaYa@jtjmkZOdNuMZV1DatvuAxDWMdxoZd8wyoXyoXGVpgy18K05TByAm1NfpjuXnoQ6Vwb4DSg//qm0WYd1@kx3fZuICdtvRDCI9p1Zi0v@xNtUSxEuqWoRT3FqGc56llh2kFjkgSKJQzdOtyfDF9lxYPJsDUoceuqM903xTI7dvqjydB19sw8mEV4ywW223Nem9tOG@o8ERetznJxfAC0oH9gaLHXHhSlbTDPNvt9w@eR0NuGS9HQ8Mwy7asYH29HrtMetEz7EuAMyK4/8KlLvVgLktVZX4zaHDpYgoiAg0ERTpyeES2iB8MVOs3rGy2zY7Y4bRhD37A96G4vx0xonhvTsljbsCBBiL2VZZ7DBl4kqGnp3VwrF0PawlxY78piJmv1@4xHQTWgSHuFMjOwwdhbiLe6Hhv2e8wzexDtt5xOxzDYW6PfheSxthNj8Gn1J6oV@JYMgLENqNr20ZfQaD62pd2BcrVZMwIHhaACU3V124G2c5mt9/hIaEF3Y9UBTZCi4zg5DG87hmcnfXbjuFesabR0rDNm5hmXHX1gQY5mB/sCxoDpsZ4DT@hBm0GxIDFSO@HGzGIzK4LZyL41@sCUsG8dpBXoaNnFN64OxOF6ohN9swekYfpJjxm6ZyKDhiSeYbeJLPoB63agttEeZ9cmMB1oioFLuD3DpWFPeBnWAlDqAaGmblzTB3LAWmyxI0N32alrGAonUsNr6X0k0WiWkJmDOfhYkRxR5cZGcvdwLwnUyVPk9D5Qo7t8@t3PYjrL1dhSowrfWjxeje0@32G3S@fo5lMEUHDfTekKq33NvPz5uQHfodbMX7p3McAag1axWN7p@3ld7UMBVR8KmNfRiS71upjrW5GM2cZEH0TGDIdqQ28AA2SfZ6lmrYHr4mQWNqp@BZW2HPsS2hMq6w5s3uWrBegCoL@2l2XGtYE0wPvIuaEWPu0ChcA/gEa4Kp9fqUFhhoVxKFpU5us51oDgIKXn42CEVoGkiHG/wz5nHd20MAnEIypeatfwgDgxzcBuY8/3TNto55gsBrEcFwbiNWSnA1IKgNHQizAWKhQAQ0c4VFWMev8bv92@vAQ8W62W47YFuX4OxN4iSUCnwsJczpBgHVu3qFgAl8XceXLI4Fq3zDaxON0eiSyoEJTrjTOw2owG6o0JQ66rw0RjAHdo@QYncmfgQxmzrKdfcXZocsqFivf0JnQsZUB5U7VV9ngbeqkFw5xoRu0N/E6Zqf1dlvTyX6U2K6nNxXMDCqfklPRSPn9ZBYLLpSkIfMn7KOfzrbFp0vN1zzHbsf7I7zp2kaktFm/VnL5hp5JjOJLZpNtMKjlk0ymlatZauY5pt1PJDaDFOmScVKqtWuvMrFxUJ5JHswQ0N4gGh6uRailxZDU0KK7zPZClcsDJPleFKxLneA1scozORYKxYSbDrnlAgiQ1pEsHCQT4UM6zDKOfKuQ0BdkEws2sN0bMqukEDlHhinmRSSaSmWjVCQPUdKyiOFhPTQfZltXv4nwOjWJ7feC5LtJuSwfq8XBG80GCzbIm0TVNg8BZiCfeGEng2k1gpJKOaEjyIYfpVWSUAkM4hMZHstGODGRgAjCWfW@KG1sOSkZUJpx5gHXYmKl@CV0DiXlFtnhFeE4UMl6lKxsYCmJrGqysNk0YBDjcgKcLmo/UDcCXixwGsPFBEuE9PX2EsxqXC8IBg3OaznrAHtwRaxnIc4D5GHxCwUwGNP48EPOZ02EFtVgqjY@xqSHmu/kt9XvApN/m7x1JWPnoYEJGwzqgVVi6fTnQL4FfODYk0Vsto@8LRgU18XxgRZPzDQWqYvLMed3Y0uPJvGkSkbJRmAcyed57YirUkbsILUUFgQzFXq76sLbpAluCmXwidwC4nsg8/gpBxgrwKj6nCFICACIzhkZr4ANXAwK@6ZqtLtAsls7mfJFPQpPZQ1A0d@DsaifIGguj1R8VY7l8EITFmItCxR6dxgOTK6KqjwVQ50cD7sese70ZiJ2giDARREJzeT0HtPcBnD3HdmYghYYM0CLIeAzvB5DETlAiholLil00WAMxOegi6DPgGjDygf66vt/3KjBPmH530MwBpeRP3dG@f2gjseR9d2T6Dnc3LacJbNmD8ZmXOeRbg6Y5nKgQhQV9@NqLXYMA1vFYDWbuNwOgulSy4wHDpPBtBI5ExYlxEwr@GwdAAspBQ6U6HrHiPWAqJyO7lYqPEWU8y@I4duMKODBh0DSfofA2XszXEDRZSgSLFiaXR6i857bIoUZkUkSP4FSs2MJY1R5YxthCPA4/Hd3yDHjaA8tC78DmXC7FZQWF3cYWFoC1pSg7s9e3zJbpN3gse/RIyBRsEfRbFJs6KDMpkGZBGBJywFAARkw/HDrnOyck7KYUqMjC3VjGhus6Ls/X77rODaMABItFG3Xb6SF3Zy9J4EIJGlR600b1VMylNJXqM0WIYE4leTmZzL12TDt1m1xcXExWknWYMRcXN8G1ga5NdGXAtUkulVwIl0MXpciSC2PPKAWGXSTvziTmoXKBw2GIs/1bs5/SzyqV5YusfqaJZxGfCrQzzBgAreID8CSVWg2dihKv30BFc83OeO23cdY7ablmXzTCZ/q1zv2iFZapGaDjHBcVgyoKL/e3Sa/mgnQBykCrm3KT52eF84vz2/N25vwumcXUSlWvNaFSkF@ql7t0nQGIIcrZSkXVLhTlbBmEj2YtWUimU6myCmocaCLKJ2Ulo/PWTiUNmA1T5@dJaFTRPmetrkv4htmiogRNBeVAgQdk7VQyd1uG/JvKhZJJQlolmQXVrZZMQsu0sBE8qjSOpbEGOjz@Dm@Y7UwmRsMbtFL8Tk2nEIZK73jyo8Hbt8i7OI5mQGHWQOdSXl8A5PdtCZvDyAmlVUY1Owz56FgenzodrhVt48/uwV7MGFJvfXq4t3tco2y6uncFMoV6ibB5kJWhVdx2DriBNWgbsVkwwDbA1QpLgoYDzPyy1WKqwwhMbfFCRKaLFpuDDXgNCZ4OU63eeBW8LpR3e6wOhITCKeV98ktLFomDzyxTkOUecOztk3HjVO8K5AnW8iwUvlWXVwC8@TQPbNMj0DEqbJ90NBsETKAtkC/bgS3AdmwVeaFU55xoRtwgAhAUhtIWShLmGAwi7phDUIkTaE8Roj9KrCj9bzs2KKdG7iVxwzgDRo6mKiM3U/4/4oJUruWFoxMkfXD2Lb0F/H4c3XmcnQNC4ED5/OwYpTqFeFI5ID3@Q3UEUaql29h@bZP01IHpdbF5QZfAWcDtQKuikorGHWq1fdYCKfcSWtoYmj7XWmGEn2CSp7qXUlBP2uJ6BlIZyshYKGm2IwHWaYGGb4CsjLHcXMJ27WvTdWxs5NwuoAZWVMU@mEA@q3mBjLa29os789t3FnJosalgLdK2UayTjdvyYHTZjuVcOiwNAEiauRwn7H0bzZug5fh6H0aU@ZYaaOvSsUcTNGgYgb14dTnQN3WEzBN87jXMAmx2pUOAOXU@2f/eLoghWqlQgPJLX4E@QSUjWCbriIEtFgKIRQ8L6QZ78ntGvzsaM/sifXC7iU/GQxqY3JKlgwgJpRIj/C0ljQ5yHgLjXEa1pWtW3XdJJ0DjXVSvHqv9mLTChw3UMDERjKGyKcaQTnV42L/IuM7zY3wrMBWonZ7j6/nPc8Ci8SeGErJqsriXTy4m86qKv3GKYsU6y7eN6zxyqRDzcNdozcQ9NIxWHmNxcmPSMbN5ZOScpjmHj00/UE3@lG0QpJys/2Umg4ydShfkzQsNk/xpd2DEjFbXYfFzUDGiNYvDBNEFXVmFlgcBEPWSIJlYAIv5zgDUurZhmT3T3yeDvWWj7pIj5p1DriVicakhRHBkGiCQc4NDOMmgUT2co@xLDn8MnJywgoqf403qGu18OsT2zHFc0Cs9ppFNoRg0fU9E5B2v3875Q0DAU@3S/O7Jef754c5u42jr9GktP/DcvGU2gUe0jUYPlFkLhsOcD5YNLYS7QDum7fRMqJFE@fbKOnYcnwsPuGrwsE8CE0ocBzuNg/0nx1vHX4rC0Yxu9gaWjmWsLE0ABDhOCOZeNC2n6YBsYQ/mYgLh4vDJ4YHE8tmLg/2txs7u0eFpBM3rgWXq2jDfv7qcV6HPEIRpuQJv@kOrPb6cQ2rqmBVBMBvUuaoMdFOmqvCrYhjPFLWyHEagiIzTo6qiFVhHO7fLilphfb3d1MtlY7XdWllZ6@iddnulqJVLnXKpWCrAz9rqusHeEbiqGkOy3ICLW0XQgIR5QOHpoeVWpIQDqmgLJJbRzHIFsfcUrlUqGWsr6/p6a319XS@utZf1YnnNMFbXOiuFgrGqFTrNslZevrdwkWKgaBX6emQBglGHxgKKBOaXgsfYcOCFB1nvhrWLxeJqq9RZXy62S4WVdnO9UCq3m9qa3lw3Cp2VZa2otVtFrSLTokUVuEQXOgylShtEUxmlahCpxORkGu1iWmGVq@6C4SwtI4vpy1VzVBxExApGDMSaOZpmRfgqhvdwkTyUWMkbBArAMgHiWnnObcrAdQwMVsnH1o@BJQo@OSt@fiKB@VYr3CHyG1xnj9TjVtMo/NrvdMaCixR8peKUZYXByxTMV9nH17dFZaeiZgIH@FYIH1@dn4lvKmomcICvxPHhqv5sdBMxs0ADZKuEDHcBzMQ1ETEDMMC0RpiiOwfCuDLFzds2IPKaGT03UYB7nXDj9oAQFW0WEEESsMj7QbMaeqPXM0NgGRKJAjULJj5tNUxcChI7E0kdMwwOwHmzFq0GqBeDyDiRIdGoIBFvQbm5IEqTRd6ArtMfRYbSbZHXvWeKMRoh7mU@Fmi5HJUMdyySUz7fRtB4zVdyGmIXAY50zjxOQUo9cEC3ODBxTaMzxk1igXXiPBaXJpZxI1sYUwyXkJh6PXvtKx5FxBmlaV85ZFQIXI1CTishlgBF78qaTtkBNYx@xkCnCjUdw@f2XrNDPzMAUCCZtFpSBJmEhVgEYoieP6YHGodnlWDczD2WfdPoDEBDzDdNG90fAFPXywTZaTbNeaDQErgrQz5ngFXY8QC09GJuJadJkwAuK8F8xm3Up/uHBNjUScEdXxthY43vD1wfUonnf/l@Gzphuou6@oj05MDRsI0boo/O3B4TSdFDP7N7N5SIqGHI9SGULR2Xo3UrcMxGTb2vql3d7aE6KrobCBR/gBLuoTVecm6nks/ZmVQYNfL4GgyzzR5rzYAm2InlIp4ZGSAsR29TM3AzgWlQIhc7m3eDMeQKc0QYBBYzL6MZqzos3Ebhdwf@gP/izokPdaPZx@99Q1RAFkp6UzNAfdCbpnFPp7v61aDtqCAFU5WxYKszYMPakyFT7Vj6FXc20Dm7@ryCrnl5CbKWeM4Du@mC3kcKe/6GHh@iC88eeH21CZ3lw8AhHw2F3j05uBb/nQdiiq2UgWN@q5kW/Tyg0wPiInIBcZcaGvd6qZFGMyea2dKbIzRjdD@eyjBDEgqB59RamUxhGafRYF08uk1rfnqceyn9@vrs1HyXGW@SWapnnu8uU7lxneos9pt9oGNh4jJ7uqUW2xHnXI4uzeqhawYo2bTUlqV7QFq@6A7jGrqPfu4jd5yZWqCSuqHrHmIPiyO3R8xbaRdsS4zqlmOZHg5tax4HnVycDPPEfX70EzHXm7Matk1yptdVA9dsvuC0fFzmnkNoD@ByfIUZ1/AjlJNz5jVay7nB71zRoutcG/x39kT3dmapHsCxVItIwmzNnFHarQ9RKm6Vop/Z7Xg1s1x@y5oZPj4GpPknqrw@kK4903I8dkK/9zULyNKex39nU3S0BU3dVmmtLOqenUwUqs9ywgI9p19169KxVsuXeR1@5nb@wO3gnCCeD@V@AffStA9zLykfObYmnnPZ/lXevfpQ39GyjYsbGiLOe2bgWSxMLNjOryBoErhLaXbl9gplSpnLcxvDvA5wW90bfSSf32Jmmde6cmbpj0jeBvEPE6yXweG7XAb/Nrmt3J9b@2HsaQrt2ocqEencK8uAiYx@p7qUFQvaR6bQCoWHM6uONTAGxkxeddh8beDe@nu0kIcXqiCqsSQswWgtQztwAPVW6I8PKjXO4ei7l8HolgmD/IOSzkx@1wcZvY8q9xE4jtAxnfDSHvTHOndMi7OP72@5bl@ObKc9VkiM@ViOVP6wPDUmyHsGfe9VrrgyiOt@teVCoSDkm4htf8xzn9K1HKR9bfLfsYwpJMx5zFQyA2doVoauNq88FQ28D@NGxXkWAAJeX8/bpm34I/yd1wWzuGvTcayP6TJgsm0T5TWQQnER7ENdNyULiZ1xLLR1eGgpaXbmWTn4BCS0UWg9VLTv6/2oGfpB3ari8j2MyssJ7/12n4hR@0O5wLROxiS@jcSaL2gKC4qWK@fW7h2BXHx1moal88dwdeU@fOu55XvxBSKKkItpnQ/XBvlqYLi6nJjgU/0RNJbZBqWma/QM8t6jDejt1wNPPuYCDR38zojO0drrvHR9ExiDjb9jK48R0cl3bFDDfN29NFCPsXCHgAidx4zlysPMxt3v6ZcGP193H7cMTRu4jZprf6FztpGjwnfgtSAZ3wZzPynAYLoyRp58zkT4bNSC/hz0Pmyamxj3Ldq09aGBnsvPXHD5gGxod52u3TW6fFdU4Js3PIAifX4y8r5KQPnFjitGPCq6ayvaupZjWQ9pXeSRnGM6TmdmuXbx0Fobkn4U3pHehAjx@KDZD@Z3aiSa6OeNna4xgGnKc3ynb6jkmwdqoYGI/87jpHIR7Ntanu61CkCLyOe3xf9BffRSd/x@nx6NvjXw6IeSqnTWcFZX7lE2D6EK0@fbsDjtGpdOs9U1P1SkpqH7tnmVl1Yg7r1Xm@1HWsFk6g4G5ywTGs8d5ZAaatH4E3zsz@vSyDLPzNpvD1x3hHX3HYd5lnMTcoXxHSSBsZavMaBjXp5izXRGNMkAuLdQ7qG7Z6FDLLHOJSkStVGsVo0CiCnaXLvR2AZXwbporW@OFDRRbypMZH3tYwyeYsMHmf7MiF0WwscoZWwZfubUZHcHl940Y@Pm@DYIVPgzs4e3LvEM8UQH886E@Ua3xWPm9BusPN63YFK6d8UklxfrnaoxmGv/ssy@x3@Z2inOxDK9fj4NNZqt/4quaBsdvqiBrg@JcD3HxZNSICuoLdfwWmgTRzbLBSPOUmznEtitarEQWMLOrML0kv3sno5OZeoXz41LHfeRHpi4pdSaQQSAeXL1/iGIvzvQPfO7A8c3ZuKcXMV/CMpn@qXZejrWCxKhbF2x6ZA/xqgdg6Y74qZrenRgRTpmjxBOZrQiP0MLmzC7Bye/7zePRAQgsb@dqftM7oMPHGj4x3h9Zl7j4qVYjJ/L1EyfTKriObOes3c83GdbuBn0@gNPPGbnTpuPorbl3hWFezcmcDz1DTBY1tUtf7b9OWJSBcFJzHShc544/T3Tci7Z98oFBnIWzLwoXc8hrCcw7x7pPowAewaxUv4PXOVEi4Xq8sq9AUIwlplq2qZ/v3XG93VQeOQTK8RlKjxemT/A39zjj8Wgns5ulYN7RRGYskctC0/7f6xYz1ltf5Q/odP46AwuBIgSu8jG2BYI5eRhGzdR5eveFZsKzpiOPfBVPL5w3@yxeu/sUWHD8mqEPFjqu7vPXiiSSi67Lb6v90MCpQFa3cCzRqFr7q6BGcRn2iB5zee/0ymkerBj0J0Nx7QT9QHptvp4RIzY/Y4zS405GsHs81G6EEwgg96O0cJlxAeV4bnzDKQ0mNL6wHB7xwbuAZjgMfMTY9IDp6Vb0GbtB2V3QuhnzBehFq33jSb0vRW6Zoth85Dv6L4@R3QiqyCpeoHrg7RkWk3DfY02v6h7ngY7XainxpB0jvkExUeq6rdaXNZGO9zYOIqo4RV20nf40fF7aCJgQzB50M/DF9JzuGV7bDKcqYdN1/Pwmu8kMdr8vOK8irpG07H4L840c5iFbfJ9A7prGl7@wLQHQwpjKkhzs3Ubvnu5kFtDi4bXhSF4Y4IqHWxqxn1ofIe0F6oLYmePfa17tJo/W5EZ20D98A1DXd1tObgsJhwfuSgWOQn3AS4f7BDnuw6aQEBDYHd6ayCvU/hAUa1es0c/8xWS8d4@Npp42rBJR2d9fThLpBw/NScCJ86tSUaHw3@VpY5A7VE@PNVN6mzjrW726YdY/s1MUpHZPTeN1ltd@cAMrJPJ@D4gcfyBbmoJzvR7WXEwB8JMVxz@9XLy2qEEHWKizpHb6VkC7x0YoBLpO26OEVwqpWcyihLjiXD5/tIGMAlF96bgnQr8ShaPwTTtE6zZYWdnbOl2WClUtDtWY/FKnF1ccKz4oRP@u8M@XXpyzJOfLekXtaWkqiaXkud2hRWSAbhhgYg6E1wfg@2Y9ODlDZuAX4jk0G1GQY2r/M4IIAq8j6Wr223LYC9sWmMBmcLlNx/wazVOca/gn/9BW1xTQ9cx9UxQE6FB8Jopp2d0nZtNnq/IHWZYHa@5QRygUVj80gV1e4uBqOu3uvx2GueGvdg7LYs7L8SdVuA54raAoBS8c3H5Ac/v@bzzeGmCs1gi4yCVrBTIT4OeDSyp7Xe9HDsx6WjewA0324uLzmzfRftiO8v2WdvAbVl04pJM6pbjXNEpDCzJn/8Bv@mDzl2K83Aye7rhJ5IjHq/U6HqNVssZQKklkreG6wiQFDYy6BcDXMCiC6YoXMHTiHQFCVCkKi/goGz4LRzbWydM3WVJvLoKD8xXzU5qaev408/PChe1r1kvb/yX7@eVW9Fw8U/U9VUvnmUSpHqHhBWNLkF0GJtk8aVhnGcYHEo1hVR0w/sDr93iRIbnUiWNOU5fjBq6RInuDAqoUZzFT6Gb@lnexNGj@5eIYI0buomDTj/ZKBPR/V8eDDDwKoSaj7raUmrA11TUE5@VIEO8zUQHF7@xiY5p4q0SmGRpyN6xLhIZzKxaqQA@3pAWXmTSqz2Rm3aXo5up8ztGc0AbCq@LuWKpRtVZatQ26uSCSdvBC4XOvjofFgvq@XBt9yLvyUY9Px9@Uih@Aa3uuJDqUR5H3u7zndulXL3w7p2nj1g8fpes8s3fwCaWbo/2j3ZPTrdOX5xAL9xJ9rPHj8dIXoNURCfeuo5FVzVBu@CE/RH8J/DhxQkptqSzDbwIUVFi0bNJBCraOq7Gl7gzwprGUn8g@az0nhGJnwYQPK1jMklR@zANYB8CsWGrYeUHfbxwiom04tIcojITeTwOoKBhcIv9DF5KTRVnNWgsFRrrgU3F5ld2k4c9pMU@iOX@ZtucCYItFuR3FsTzKs5sgrtfSr37MFH@4vXmWO6vN8HcU28ADUJlmr2t/YMXx7vjyYDG6Elct7ZeEofyOHPGkcZ3YshbgugsvEiI61G1OItTAu4Vkxm/q9DwbwyolmCOrR5PTBRK5Y/HQsKElqnhVaEXVd4WqRSVAGWQKlZr4sxgxxxGiijn6Ai6W17FgAnsxQPUsuC5uMCcoDsfc/iR1UCsornk0DsiJi74ddKLij9ZOeKwajhHDzw@5uZMVcGs4zH4j8xK0lW8YEMmpjPtgqmsCF/LsC@hwhJWqfI5ii3xhogv8bLHg/LidX1QpvZrnazFtN9bnLWDWdrS@3g3mIB@7vhGhb0ZOHSeXzKTQL6gmyJ1frUmdS2/M5LuCQBBHKRTOW8Rvv29kxpKZ1w0I/4epbmBjRMVAPGLLsWJW9/Fa0j5UUh@4xxvckdcbianStKvPHGZUSAleOza9EzQDKgTOijjWMApsTai4nhRLN3kwLYsD2SSNkzfIKH4ONWCcJKjQ0j8JJJqs3gCaDIXiIxZFo8hrFebvuwKptIb0H1ar3jiJYIjzF4EZ3JjUVWh5S5BIRQHmip4TyqpFRXmuwPcY1RPTiWRRaiQS@36PSsCOOPav3Mj//43fptf9Xfug/tHwj0sPAHfrwlfB9y/LmM0DXz/LPAVwfdj7vsqj102fb@ZyF5YLeae2AK6fByfqhPyBHk3LNUl6G3s6c/3j5jXwltHsS97oOeF3YQcBmkOdHOgvx4QxTX1MYLzHMIuDPGkzj4HEgG6AvpA8QYlGsrPcC9SeMtVJZ/HgqM9OUf7vIwhX4elS6/eDPCyRxDC8qul1RUtD4VUryVCuofjEo@dcISKUgGeGLs2@7VXoBNvbGywuNfSLaO2WuW0kV/Sv1qOvwoKugSwMa4onDFIA0nCFBBXF8lSS3pGUzApTmRJLYk8re1wUgNpMEUOAFEw2JYn90HcdERTAR3bxtAniWkkFSBg2LYTueVVIlIBEceNVxJODsfwKAmaOCIDNBfthvhLBDtBsEp8FrGefcXO/XP7QlxNyYDwfjaDdG1w/5MZ91VyysKbSaYvSkxNXnOItWGPT2wHLUV7UFqWKuaLy3ltVYlQaFyggvLiUH8HKGFwA7NoGeZrp@9tbe/uf3Z4dDJ1YQ5BJifBkixZ38icq7ns2UXgSAblHm/UJ3v5k2dP9mRTRksV2moQItxnN1nMWblNlnRO7i/5qZ3pvCliKiOt8FDEtIFF3aP9qdPYw9h8BHCbHxqYyjWl3N6dXWzUz@3EVPbvZl2CmsilkbjAde7RFajJyWJiEYP73U/xfncvJ4@kangeFQ8q@c5VeFpWBEQiOLjEAhwglstLqBkUKwtwyO0z4RUVRX7BvEesj9tw6GrKoEQRyFN5FT0OrfBGNXGVWFf3upbZjMHc3cbr9fhFIPKmi@AKkZzXt0w/pcTI@lFDCQiYWEpcSD@sDHO0AJWii1AJV5bddzuZxKfEYBAAvuTRwOuyI6fPQtPTjiFdxyCIsJ0BX5Ew2GeDHsB16HFsIIs1QDRRITE0VDIoKleoYWSJy8mGGbwADvI7wyvKRMVzvXYpNVRyXWPYNi@BgaeULIz0TzSQqIIjwlhpurDMTgKP4y38KR7WiDbpR91RNwyR62d6zrTbxjCFl65ULkA0xfDkzcvrpBKfogG6KG9bXq01cWOeHIi6L0ZEeNvcxGBbXw8G2fiVhuvreHENnnaGboEcT3z3AJwwP6U6Pb3PUgO6ytFjOUbe1HnKznq@qzC1zm@DsFkmQwo1PCgCBGYE7ZCLCIel8ObjVL4GvYOhnt3Gx1uzz860XO4C3JSJwpbQmLYNUzmaoZQYKEiQpEJoa9i3rIIl4tSb45QHaTA@RndLMbzPcEY03UCIi3YwTqEtqNas/ihyJ084Anmrrq9XRG@Ms5p1BmQxzeVzeUA7g4VIARXaVxxehVbDG7rxKnfXaJvAFh5/x7BtAxoIaKanwxysD4DIXCUr30CRDW90phwSvIhPxWlYKOj4Tc@7yVsL18KW8lWyy1TvYE59dY6TakdMq6P8f5/P5au3qSWrNsqDoKPUU0vdmpZZTmcyS3Y6tWTjVP/oEZpz7pZAkmjkQDsaApC6ZClVoGeQPGpLdnVJ30gttWvFNKUAL@hnt5Dgay@fu13S7/JLj2CmzkKIywdvasmjywILuZx2B@XDEbKUzwLN3OLdavQuCsx@ycxksAy5pQYW4Ov8@UmGePb5SZ4sR1UhiOYve2K4TXDVoCemXr7BG1AEi44Gxl5Exi42JTckcHjP8/KsuDmyB8/4O3jOg9GmM8OLSv7x8ZiHMxbB75J0jxO/mpHf1ggNOExBI6I3qysKMJO/@ZuEtsriqaXN1WUnkywVqvCjVUusxD5ZOi@uJFjiMWjq@XTcjd@e75SvmdEprr5R1TO9k3tzcXR1dPSFcp5KJrYPv4prKwC6xtbp@9DPGivO@bCP@yQS6XwskU9rj9by@VevXoG4C5@zeq4ehcpdKGdq8uIstQae@tpaOrtaTmcfJxtUFCVVLConzDTz7Nzse@02fJ0uvQQmleAftrmJeYED/pkI6w07PCwsDAcRoTKtjPoAXOVaLyXY@ZqupzMrxcd2NVcsFP/8jxfvsrdHjY0//5Ve3ljExyE@fnT3DN0nWumTxcVPnjxZWclC43H30feOvtza2lrZyZaOzkqbK2phcePP/nRxsVjcKOYXLzxPu0ieXX0RLxZW4rk//73k0dF3G56H/YefZaaBE3/L8NVYqcSu2Fv4XHUY/pP7bTvi1tHd7LzFCRKE5Roxm2SytJw8@SqJ1X2b0DQtMaK/BjXDItPqm2v/9SeHbxJ@ol7Mv3Th6SfeJFbLCe4EB/iWpe86UU9sINjqXWKUr9Vq4Fz7r/8e0tc/AzwYM9qAn3pJ4lodJepqjZK8S9RXwaEVi5Dv//X978cS9SESQn1/jxXrxTSnFa38SHsU9NF5QiuvHD6GYPmh4KH8kKKracVz2Z@R7sauDYK7UHnoV@ZEwoJ@l5SRYIIayPFQOCh3Yhc/f/F//MVP/@In9PdT@v4nfN/K6uLjVzuMGTAD46dSeRzULs/WynHHgVFeBd9BEH6cU@GTa0h/Fb2qqFmiXMs2eKkCEk5EHBPtEPwy0SSB/yPhYgm5RqyesYtIF8TryJ9kWZ/Z7Bn/2Db8w1d6MQQDwGWzsNCybRNhkwaZs8kw2RmBh0lewD4GLpb4Ghp/OOPD6mE4oyrwUpPjWaRmYd2QHDbhswh/9A@fwIu/ixQigglk@rPIvv0nljhLnF1cPLXxr/kG/w7e4t8bH/9OW/h3/Ab/Tt/i37GPf0ce/j1r4l@Ul8cSKnCGTOYYREZBtA/5vIBvLtcQvoB4E7HEL/XDYixxC5@LjHp3d5b7KlOtin@QpKqBDz/cBWW6uFPVja/qmcwZle2sLgq5oV7UGS8y/eYaX20A3szG2UbN2aZvrlGHj5pccZKrzuOLr@pnG@M4BJrHjzM4aB8DnvrSBQMZvl5ndxt39buzjbu7jQ3436DfO/GE0LuNqX96hJ/qHKDgc3eBDPT8LF8/z5/X@ecC/Ll8HUNy@XNw1OHZAMCzs1jiFsmFnV3QFUo19UxbLV2ojIZEuoJxLY@xipYuLudLw09Wd4uxRDEez6cx6h1OTCBerMcSKKSvc1l9nQJevf/mf8Pv@ftv/i14oWj4CjOMjSVqjIGQs7RZsArXBe1KuwKHyQogY3YLXa2NTL1gsMKoMGKFnqO1wWXAXwFcZqHDCpesYBdsTYNIcPis4KOrA49L@OsAFhf@zEIBkReuGeRi4VRB16vS812DKeexMxZ/ZYB0ktOSuUIyt5pMmhel1f6beDbZOD9LXlQTee/8PM/lNlZcqdK9und3rNHYfb7TaOSRlM@fOYfh/@FhL@q997936Dw7dHoO/B8eHj6Djss8zqiP4VOrZzbEYzNRr26eV1SkR0mZifzG5nl9WUX3agaorIhhmY/8hBjhWV88j4FS@/LlTfXlS/y/ua7eVMkReMHRqAYAAow7IJAHAIKX1So50A2fa8JKPnTevDwPXNyRf3kDQS8ZiNnBf37M90v4N//f9f/sBUudXSgwDm7vNlL0UfBPUW7vbu/Eb11JpYQntQF/GAB@THJ7V0cnAd2C6yylXCh3dzwMflPKBkdYxzw26pQ4BIRBn@C5nidB0gDFMCUWtM7Ph4WCUm1CSGDa1t/R2ohSpV0jS01czwJlSEsrBFJaqVZXhHutXK2WhVtbXa1W0wFUATzCCUCGp7eqOJqqib6CZeBjLFVAmxndXZ@MV@KPHqXE2w42@33QbrX1wrt3QVCj0TbdRgPDl9@9izfiuG@ktl4Cf6H87h2M86QCeu9zR6xYroMWq@WLYQ5d3dN93029NfvZOO6y9OIK3S5bKCAopmaljY3VlXp9dQXcq2VFqcaX@JaT1GVmXVPulvJxXg/QR5MJEaWV1xQKvUtiPEtssM060LuHH3Z7l6DmZislJdUcGcothMgwbX2dB7KV1VQ5sy7@aosKq6eZ@Ds7O1vOrKTX0o8vLi4mBBbkSdVbvabd1W71ChpL7qotcVE57qPXHz1aXofWKReq57FGY2frdKuB7zjDVWCYCRgGEneL4Qpf302ekWWrtH5xhjW6OE8mK9XHvIfLJZZIVgWcmgRGycrrVPEEqM9mBw/QDAnrxDed6DNtbRmmmFifduOsFVgbFzRd5nQ6ixAIfcOauPbsGZYlb3a/cVyrfWO2jcVY4uhga3v3NFvcgNmquLe1nS2evHiS0NBbCv0UvYz@492tncMXkODoYHfrZPfT/c93XxxBuBd7/VY3DN0YGMZNYzC4eYOXfxsNow@h4adhtExPf/1a79OHVTlfu7l5/7Mfvv/Z//D@d3/8/nd/@P53f/rzb376Q/j@AXx/zJ8//nfrJfz9@Tf/7Pff/87vQuB/gu9/hO8f//yb3/w@/5L/T@D7nyNhfyK@ETj@ZZVEPY0fIIRysZxJw8SRXl8HYqDQjRjk9Ws//@Ynv/fzb379t@D7L8X3t6a/v/HHs78//cH8L6b7ye/fD/Pjfw/fP@S4JOyPf4eH4XMK/nc43K//1vt/8b/z/z8Tf@j83ff/4k/wR3j@6W/92X9@/yv/Z7FY/rN/8/6HP37/g5@8/8GvvP/Bj97/4B8X3//mv9EK0Z/ff//TP/pv/@EP/9t/@J/o/w/o9w8f8v/@t/4pkOtf/dHP8P8nf/RX//Fn@P@//qu/@qP/@a9@7V@T47e54//@l/@O//7lr/zwL3/wz//yV76Z8/vDe3@/eUD4N38LIQ8v50PwPKReHxvyzbcqzy/SGmEuQAN02zorggz4ZGSAdh4rsIL4gcH203/y/jd/FWj4XwAk@P5H8ME/90DUj8jzxRdjcRnS4dXMF1@AUvSFUI6@iAL9iLF3eZBXC4/fAcAXFMs/LICCTP8XhAIwJqAk2FjmBII7Bnnwz7/557@H4UFKDP3VKL6CDI3ALiHwO1nFH@GgDaoRhf0RDvv3P/v@@9/7x@9/9tvvf/ZryPPVlfXsVlbVPmA4BMDSA@AQcPUhcACooWIEGuxirAiOxQ00dMW0zKtX0AmL4AJ1JB0rLYMvptXJraEbEoK@m@b2pQxaluA7jK2sgw8tThmYbDM8KgNRTzL4VuFMbFiDOALF1xEzdNbLaEJA1bkGeDERT5NtlEHEZ8MnhAVS1jLHrJGuDXnCDAbUCQPDAmHQcVwrxjPl2g5kWBvuMMSFyDOxV/B8VauXa8M6ovuaigA4Mk8gS4DCtx1nhvWvwV8jnAAfG@58DUUp1zKZehlCalRVyi3boDy1ElWO6p5hVG8MZwx37W0@ZuyTuFaOc90empIJaPzNhNCbZOLahPjzTFpUh/6lk75pTA/9NKT24WE8fhODKb0AALyqipu94KuqWJrHED3kqDKULTwyHAO0XEYYB4MAEkQysQz1b4Y8kD@U4WM@G3wSRnRYnaWlJXBt1OPL8cYhaFbMvap4vu7iehTJhRUWX12PYzBunuE7ApeOSAFL76ThV4P/3UXaBUs1qaZjS0lUzJNM5qRmlp0VJ8ErIWtIvjRVIEOA7BOIwe/jx@CGFqJnGBZLhOm46E9LjyCzrzAllqLXxyik/Rso7LDYM@/yiTME@Twbj2e1VVxSULhtIPalU6nUvtZW1mLwJP8AX1wjXqECnYWv781tbGCj129VMlOgEwTA1Vi9LtZOmRarn@yeAvjpIdOKhRwDaf52Za24UlopFZdXV0trRW1ldX1ltVReBla2WigVi9r6ysp6eX3tjuryGLhBtpJuljbq/2jq89/9o1mf2aH4idW/YMMc2VrvYnWrxrfuLeEaavy8EK@SuYRabumskMW/4vIy/EIZs1pp7WJx0bpVscrntF/sFlepoZixW3WItt0F@LDYQowtQBh8IBNcRmJi4X//sCoWefHlc3yhN66VgHiU2DkQD0cHvXh7exv5xhKL3/uez@p1EODV/b1YAoi@G7zgXjXbuW6OXhnXHrgGxV4ytrP/@f7J/uHz3M7@CQjVX7LiciEXS9zd3XUCWzx5DXZ4eEipQEVa1tB112KDwYBim@C/G@qxfvRThW8MSesRsM1HGneWVkNnAZ0b4rRrPUbLcGfQrRcxfOfP2UVsIx9EnuLh4@fQPEBQNjvAjai@w04dvuHxidGaA7Hd5W@v3nYd0Eq@PcwT3b7iUTsmP@0YRD3V8f5Cr2f63TkQL/o9PABkuH9rGHZ7TSggGuQ5wBP4cS3HmQWwxl4czanls@CSAlzxplsKAPx4/9Onp5Hn6e7W9tPYKnty@Hxn4lESQCV2sLt3GnjXeKxMWgpQfLl7cDDpFQ/gUlVSQxdZaS2bBWYPP/jM0oeeuaWvJIiWu@elK0v5ernqGo8eaTXta3XDX2Ivak@@zjwf9MrL69p6CQgAan1pgMbsmG2oe0L39SN3yWNHB6g/oxZcq@vW7R1bWQNd@vMBK9djz3DL3brGj46YXuwp6LI9fGMOvh3Lj@GRyDa@FRdtEE18Pe2gz@YGwgOD0Omal11gyDeOBIg1dZ3B92M/kD6qxkJD3Rvg8zwobCrGmgGO67xmhxViObKRFtfLpfL6crGcLa@XV0raaqmU1YpZba28tg7MsaCVtdVyaV3LllfWl1eAe0NsaX0tlgCmZnbyeZiZtHgcnhVAa7fwIvMNvBHeyXXrsQS3/LC3@N71hB74ByxuQJo4vm7I82lDcdqsxYsruNt/WWOAUWctltjb2y7s7cXjT9CDtuDtQjzeRk@pXCisPYnHDYrZhhmmGI87PA1EAZjPPYXCk@14fMAR4O0K8XgXPburKDLH4yZ6trf29jCf1@gpYnoAu@Ix3GNJzxqA2ehZXiaZOx5/E6ADuC2e0QqVdBc9mCfG7PGYbYiLxz@V5SkUAMMxh@MYnsq6bm3F4/vcs7WFMZ9RxUu8qN9BzxZ94nEXPECE8fglOC5dw7Dj8SY4kRTj8Ra4WiMdwvDSeDxtb/t6PD7iDYRNFI8PCVpvXcVBNhThmM3Tp0/1rt82Lvln5PJnC4oGMeZwsLvX/PTT5uVl0x1t7X56jDGfffZUfz0auM3LpkjWbMDHgTQQc9UbTX6gjPuNhm7NjPkOxNgTMY1Rw8CyNfQ3UCbxucRMeo3PIOYziJm1NsixwacHoE38POnB84nepBj5oRh6DpvNeBUJ1R/1DTSO4Zih12Zne3rLdaroH9YWk6lkdnS2WrioUjDrpZTbQvUOYzspemUb8kLldnQ2rBUuQF9YK4oTCan4@bBYMuPZxd4mMLXKor6pFVcywwreeel0kiypapsp7VH6beq5sllcXqnEzzc31fiZdrFZ1MqV1bWv0oN4XKng7@byWuVtqpAsMIY/ytnaxeZaKZJibS2j54uVtTWlegct4cOE1Bz4RqORSt0Y@pWiYFlRkIHy87eDj6iKZrWTGmaHNV4oNlKqw5oGzNkfwERUmMLVxssFBvheJI7xEtANNwsVZMmpuLZejkP@@byCvAi5BzxfvZSrDsEj4hhz8k@OVVT@SjWtvKrkcHt7w@k06HUz7FUUEuXX2Es8hkJHUOWWMZL0vUrsFMVdegk7w2tNmvgWRzr1C9oWvyKDcWOCtrYei9WFwHfEX9pQFV68iiC3h6/rddwcvmbSH4vhB@VlEDsZgVjQy@0f5l7Ynt4JsJwaQz/31MA9YS0Zts3PieZ2h/iectOxq7fqS/WODifjyVK8mQGmP71WB5feZinKnenKDdWrUa/XGrWe0ev7I1ArqC3qQWKYTNkTxiHxkIrcp9@oPYHqFqo23lFkoHdpmBjG6m28ceFJ7cntoFIB2LuqUaMXEccTeLBn064NqD5HhotnSvYPlzrMwMMbre6r810E3Iamvb1T6y6zq0Ep9j3ePsExASrQLRZIRDRqhbvqZe0Mw9/hz4Yaj1@o6tm7i1gdhlR1lNBr3qDJX8tVaII@slodQpi2tlLtsmat@dWw6tb6IEWzqgWNFdEOmF4l@HcWzI6NXKM2DKu9XDsrLhdxS1C2WFjPFjWYEmGqBGj4roF/Bb4afCFeQx0iZaXijMWzhWEhp2U1Q8v6zq4NrVyoVLCxoZvIC09dyRTTVqrtMH1DpU6DEVqlIurZLuub2W4KUh0busXBFTWlvtlczaysKEr1DZTOXUq1c0@UzZVqO/WENRQIgIkdvkW2ulLt1FJfKdXUolLzjDfVaJenlFgdBznVuL8IjSsUI2/QOyuwxVUte6s21DtL9/wlba1YORssnakaVK/w7nIj/r16/ALa/o7F4C@6UgFCQxXC5JDmYkYoKIRhfRQSLQO6SlsvVgVIrC/YSyqewvey8i2HqWRyrZhMKskqquCLEC7YE/GSJDC25CNtMw6CSrwSXy@CvhVhS1NF4ItWq6AK3cXaptdnK@uxxG3s7vZuI7rR7TtsNNIzqvQ@YuwysxRjeVqBzTUSbJFcaq5OdpKt2tbl8VZVQG9txxIV2hsU7u9g5@J4pppf/Nhl38xG/Sv@PMctC5BrjO7UOGMXYp27uAx1bkf8UD/vNsZbla/k5zcy9fx5LB6nkcoXvcolhZeUfZ2gm6fZ9q1843jlGWqzLKVX@Ag8u1C@fm5at@VltU46X4olvs5Ai@A2p3r@6wQw9DtqaLHH6Pa2f3sLWuYdHjkuLpdiCduR249Ak/SB08FMUCrF0SphsP7J@ldrX5W/evbi8MXhHntcqJQr5ag@cP44m9WSWnKDPQYB1DzeBV3jHXNK2tf2Z7TDKlFNVPrJ5ZXk8liyWmJYW5HLlSmtXle1jSLbBFplFeA3HW1VLbyrc8KrU8RqEWLe/@pvrQw3yuAvgpBXgTYtZYr1upYuKon@@2/@LR7lud39fOuAJbGCf/2nv1dc@@s//Ve0lJa8q/JKryUAEp3a6lriIsGLsLLGFPDQelxRS9TzIlxb05SEp3IfFK@U8N6JSxVSxUIZ4rYPuS@@Cq2WWE/EEuVnr94xtgFKX719eWkWyZXPjylSSxVQnuCffY2WnK/VxVfASzxvKQ/p2ToCS@tDul6vp9FOy5L1DJ4@K5bI6n12V73g1gHUINI2/RleGv@Mr4KAtOeBX/rAm94wWKmuMVA58vn3v/qbxeLqX//pb5wr7xrvGt8Flrq@vr6qFRN/M/3JpxdiLL2wxZL8Pkc@Y@NVzsHJvOTYe13RkpZeUHdODre/s3uKU7Zh45UlbPvweQ6jTvpGKzxa2bIM3bVG/ERjZ4RQONOfbh8xx2Uvdo4ozUs6VEuhZBETuSzttyvidXLZa6bllnH5uZQvrOS1EgOJrLBWKa4yHdibh5doCNcSJmVUrW2nP@LqYmpbocQLWwiDcQcm6O@eUWGfHh1QCuIe6YWd3WeH7PD5wZc5GcrDT5/un7CTw73Tl1vHu1CPZ7snLL51wvZP4uzl/unTwxenbOv5lwyij7een@7vniCCfAw5I8qzvMEC1Y1teCMvj8KuR/rbWLDntK4Mfzxcd/t6Hu8rHw@28XVnBr4YaDx8YJugHEZVw5OtBS4rMkSvt9tuDE/zmi22gGrhQhrkCzxM3C14a6w0@OJtwS0tstbK8@QaaxWe28sba8wqiD9mrfSWj9ni4uK5HQ/mlWg1As00GoQHVyAsLNP@93YXUqsrLA36aHFFCWOeHx4tFKRv4eXx6YIWxB3vLBQDz/7ewnLg2QXfSuDbe7mzUAp8T7a@s7AaJnu@vbAW@HZ2txfKgQ@IdGE9xPl8Z0ErxGRjXYMMuEAv@E3t7R/ssjQAKdWxWDRMomMiGBoiBVIbv1oFm5yl0zddJ0uqTnM0Ad02PgQtwcegFlBwPMN2vciytNOHHxBJARiS0ekYriS5l62swIrX@8GkE7uNLWCFFrBCAL@Ah/oRji3WWFFhEL3QEZoUvyYoy@IvPDq6@4nHNlAdqAMxZOm@QDrCDSkM8Xry2MKdQJnqkPG2Q0cDCFSDksbduKLguc/nLw4OeGZ9kndTcYJkXPidgdPpAzaoIvxi1SGUdw7vFuoLbKsFIavgK9Rjd2O9GZvsTWwKqOfCQgsQjLfutW5lGUprWdybgXjRw4/0ADBEg7sALn7gNZVqYV0vDb9FBVKwMXcP93gNcXdHjY33ssIwU2opiuaHhd69Y9J37o973XGvneS4BXJeLI6Pl7SGsAqGLciTxgRBtypQygWkmEwGUkN1KC5SrwVodPjySxhkKeuQUSHJHj2icmyAbz1JWWC6DOXIVARBBKLBqPkQWVC0RSquspBP09k13FFFV07jPMKvCm@OggtkgLNOFnSiV4NRGHTngg3acnWCIYuoThv7GtzLxQb4kT0CJWdZE4ZJlslIbRUjUVvMMiPLOhA8wVMbpg2Ua7ghT5SkAIORev/5Du8hflsShfMAqjHwvQp1GDCLRzh8idAXFpquoV9VJRTwQ4ICukWiSWFDcLj70x3vULI0Hy9Ilpj6ISn39yqSjnhqIAdBadSseMEFpxVRXQqsh0BT@AUyHL81QM9JkiPLZAREQGUCbHccTlU53J2kyw9UYneyFosfXQtky3NrsfvAavxitYBpLSQRqAWw@BTgzQA0/Yz3ZnEWCpgLCQXV5tuhgAk0pCUY42MIHpAeptwwvfrx6WGSrkwOZRi30IOcK/Ak497WuLc97sXhCyE629hgxRXQeZro0lbBhRcdsDI42pxXjifsjHvJmFRjhkzTCTgwzwFoDlklB0MCnGbGyEFyHr4DSe/hW/lqbGuvsf9893Q8FvHlvIYoeNd3bIvyUMbBRIEw3kuhRwlKlOpgI3B5M3XE88hSezZOTo93t55loXwK2whHwKQMAD9iJIzV4E7mAKG20YL5uJ1lqZMtllbYIyxZlgkbBHoenIXleAagmptje9AvUlYFDhL4x0dSAkdkbEZW8RRLKezd@TlMqYU1pvX675Z7y/bacpuNltdQ2OV4AhlEcHnJYJ7zocmFDYRs8/trKzMze10osBV3mflGFyTuYcGdxk/1usO5jaZFebK875BS5lUZXlyJvEVcXgPz4rhoc78USXMj0gGG4jCGMJzOyfyYIfkcyZNipYDFy9I2PrYsH5Jox8ui8rJsUKbTZRDaa@w0amjGlUVxW8egaZmoh9Lrr9k@2tpH8vKmLOs50GkmulpOn55opBJ2dfB5jgW/dNsYLgHTTeLGsG85Jt6Lh3f04Bq9G97sm4sd2qwHei7Zm7n528Sr7cR5d7rWh98gSOdtYwut1tiLzyPvQ38FWlLfvlSBujvmJVPVVsfSLz1wWG1yvYqdBHebYA6WqUMLUhbaQUPXCiWhb9NFyFg4fKX40fNPGV4mi7q9ND7plumPaEMxClm0qdjAi5c989oAtoO3QBntXIyrsQ9S7aJhaM4aD6MzxxMKr@55hjuh1fZ5Qkk@@fRj3K39OJ0XdIMniBu62zR9fKNHg9uYGzxHKcj3xxUq2i4iqA63iHCyo9P63NnTh@ibSIUtRia0cAEVlQTIUe8ZUoVKp/uEkoRJxj0RzOn@fNxm7/KXhXoMd9s0xvA60FYDaCsaZVOM6BOPNLcACPgOcaDdL/ZPG@KqMK43BctW96iRkVauSl@/ymsQKb8o@bSuiWwTio/3jfArP6Gq1w6n5Tgpc6jzQW/Df0SFpFdXYdERW5@m2LOVC64WFUgfkQ0epHnEKeFRpFSPwgZdELNEQAMPTMe1Tg4yXV9E3HENgwBIRZVW9AkN5pdMe3N6pmnp9hW6qlz/Z2nPbUU6iy5BitQD9cCgLkIp5AuXUG9IGuj2YUHjbtAtBCC0fNnNL2wczmRExDS8h4OsUSTHPMQFLj28W7aVCqPTUo7gdVNkThx@IqtD4NpOB80FjjviGeEFDqlqFUBQ@CCeYNhSBY/Uuha2BqIjSSVSCqDbqgzCvWlGWM4su7@0PKtFIgcSa2YXlUs4CHUWFOuCZzWfF0J7K9HKjCUNG0fKReCEqd0HSdwyOoLiYBojGuEq91SrcPE1oCLG2@mscAH/bDPqqXBrBA4oA01AyEIUHMZ47cNE4YJCI2g9GDqYVUh61FFolsIuNIkWmQkSA4YzM5MZ66cI8jMT201jGWrt1IxYYENBjUTTi7YnGBL0oTe4fYF1uFjK2zo20USgQaCBRpYavAE1Hsn1cSCJ4P1CSOCcMvlYFg1alX45CAM3xYSNEnDVu2kDIe0QMHzXuembQ8NKAcNs4BVofQZBQg7r97mDIAKZDIKxs6nsgl8tLqYg1RnB5csX7BFLaRsbqTU1RUGflBUlGIwieTGSPJIYmHS9zlLFdGpZJl7BxIByeRzBymwERY5gJZ3SJIKiQKCVAAMXMQjJJ6CSEdWOIy5HEAd4L8Zh8CK1GbmnixntYmOjjIprJHAicXF20dPLmSIk5qgXMuMxHC2PiIRfjNcIkC8XI/NIBMVKZhlQ8Kwz4xFhrhMRQabRPFcuZk5OvzThRRqf5eRDyfE@Z8M9K2N9kVK5pa3PwN33XRGId2r26WbNMIyTdBrJHGQEGpKQW9fAlaAsv1lVTFrQftWJWTFi8SUIZAPUCBKPmWWv75vrmh8/2SFwh27F4XUGdTXLyqCGAEcBjlGGxMBCqA3My0ar1w/gYCouK9yMxScwyuS5gzdlX4N03yaxX@ZEbIw3H16SBfjEzZY0h/D2TUGCxsH@E3x8vnuMZoD9559CFy5gPbIs/JXVXOQYgypu6za/1N/0TSgC8Dau0Ii68q4azx8DZf4Cm0Qu4Cex84RUO4RgPLGQDokuTL9hOgIbb0pJR4ZP7UiXPwYAZaUKega7MZhuYXOM@KX1ZX5HJK3kUWpqKnAECUUBsYWwzU6Pt56f7B0eP6OWO2psHRw93ULMoGC2dLcN6PtdHQeIbRsWn1SD9ozh9HuJ76fBOulNeesZf3MPwvLrcHnjAWCDYhoUOlkirC8n@il4HjwrAXGUABqEikbb6M/AjQp5ACYq481AyHuRl1pMhaJMs2ZCmvCmZ0LJR@vI6agtHcOzkz4Qtk9X0dmcn@QlviegZdKVuDRyUY66JHpx@R2gy0V6MQDSkTfoo0XMaMejza@3WoZHG9LC1geUhtWhTARniTQUhMyufcg/uME9mHsFDroXmSbdQiD3hmLuuLAI0iNvu28l40YEJI5Fyki3UqwksUjkzN9TMCY6muMi47zMeG6veW6vITfOcNnrSYHMvDh7PSaIzWoeUzbPay4bS8mMiyeBfYx6rgOD3uviXnGyhXCuQx2G3URbJZ3RGK97JLvskRzF4UicLdzdL5SJhh2XyMSEE86fQmFut6HZUlO2DTLHk/Y1cLH/ucc2btBDMyVfvZEqBsETpTRAnJZwkn3iwtBcykBMwA1pCeBMZHdBk0qALyUQMlWWR4nIGrS0LKwCpg3cIlxxE3UlUdLxhKIYCUS2KmZhty0HOUGGk5nbnlylQiAM5auooamVr03yjMropDuVa4QaKSSUWSmCy6qqCgkUbtcgmQbYLdaBimf6s6tRnq6GqJyUyUxu1kdWJ9waZwUI@g70HgiVmVdn1jtSD7nCh4mVSMUKVWEWltsUXhyxZW15ObKn4fDlc7a6Gm55wDMnbKVYCPdR4OkTtroe@1Z2stCewOkRB47oUCQrpBlU3UEWNCwLBjF/tE2c@rFsXC0e8seoGghXaa7BeoIdi6nBYz18W0vTwLeS4GvIfaYNtVxsAZjiaeR9N3LyBsDLge7ii7r4wjEyco9e20cZUkJ6t5br8Xfh0NtggOPTixy9gWtwAzCEtJ0WvU4GcVA66OlBj7YIZ1FguDZc3Ntk@mL30gLxHEEOnDXUORHIQMkc6pI2eBMKlkAjGo0svBlpWsbW46YX4SqSuHJ6UKBSnh5oNKXJm@OxANS8glSojbk7tiAaeGqaIX08LW4wlUMyAA5Z/yzT4PQkw5VTqYcLNHyOmdb8zYsZxhiirlZ0Dhpii0lUVKcLRS7sEQeQ6zotaYfgQPQYXtD0RLi4NootiO@SMbktnBGPICmCZimaUlykOr11JY8gUfRC8O4MoucajD4FAigzsQoYrPkKCCR5hUOIBd9JCByfHGIYxQGl4AM1LbYbEgTiCBbxkH0ThUgtHN2K0AsQAddrSezi5ecLbbNrIcYoZcrX2SZLSlFKZCzPBuNVFmBYuwgYFIr4UTrYQ8nBXhyFi3kSkEpPBqn7Cj@W20MLL7KbAhpriQcWPWiIO2Grm4UUEveca/7OLLFwJsXMSP9wIQk6URAC0SyNe2GqEG0guQIvXTOSgsvMMo3kJBQjdjJMsxwBFTjSRbnHQTL0wMwZblaYVVFOybKqsprUg/T@Csvs09Q4XlcxLKJ1VbXpyq5FKiu3ToxVViSS9ZzetGaDo4NvKKNNZTihxMV2jPgn7Sz7pI2LISIkOkfJ1pjF/8Y3cEQG5Fe1cEQG9QvKSjsBAg8fq2LtEFl7lN4xHeItyEGOLzCgKUBDcMeuyhe18FQLC0KcAaFnLF1REWbngJwlik4H@DVuhqPTwwdFiSmkGMJSY19zPDQF0evOIsAS7B3xeSyAEsDiS1yisBEqEpx5bJBK6sCITEbMZ7Uxa3C4K2QuIUaxCN4Z2Xdxb3riKdOlGGEcnyZn45BJxHQfjv9qtCCjuQXB5qA1IjHXBWtGfJ/X3S@6MhrKbn0huYHc1S/CzxshiAn5rVSQckCqH8oLgXbA9YGobCAEbSkMomEL3yqY6vP9HlkGuc@FD7dNvuELfK2uiylpW2M0Ge2fizIkXsJiRC3qR5SY6WJS71CL9nmfjJebOpIMIQF2Xo1H/TNEli@quAzInRltqlZj6Bjt3CBrXJXvaCRRFk/ZkJ4a3dKIHZ/GyuOSZahn9XHHg9ztQCjMXt8y@DsOtYPG1uF@@MZL8cYXw3MwyMs57mX@xrwy8xwwdiL24qvGAMc57rznMY3dFzCV4S56P8dODL5ZwRBvNnxF6qQxUF5hItzWbwNwpwMSr40vIJIvxBIIvFy0sBCte/z1niPHaYal1/GtyKCT8gJkqeweFP4SGmbQpNfTtHTfM0ZGHhPmmxb89HQ8658HlTyPNcwf2sYBpD7B90fmXuvXemwnUjB6JdRErnTwJqai7Yhi8LXIfPcI2hB8eulL04G@gZFr0E4JoSTQ@T3HtkbMxn1Nl/SiaUavQZDvvcQXJ@ILgMSiDm154O@bXCmsrxKz98QMR@lw/s7lIK6kxPh9@RUmXspYBWpGXYcnH9vTMrEngw/M8U0UXM8fD2vhiYMP79MItnjk85G0jv2QfR@z9njQoQZo9nk7P/J5NI/2LXxp4o1Otyyw7ZW1wmqF8bezEhniaKG3WoQSuzHs463zuDEA53GZ1jKuDYstYzd@bnoDADzxB1ClWKLv6pc9XQKmlisMs4kcPCD9emybUhjlONZ4SEfHCSPUqOk9V0wLsdG78cSsgo0pgsW8YCjAteBnkzUatuP0WQUcbXwpJU0G@JoRmQLvxNezTUygK/VUU9mEZwWeUHQ61Q/jGAd/LdiUj/uJHJOdwTC/YHKBIl6NUS1g6Nd46asyPc4cCBZZ0YEJm69qwIyQZg2hjHIrAUDjHJbicB63e9LiuQRpO/uHaLWhDGHE9lNBDFaRH7FSqnP3lKRZZE8JsATcRI@ESfv683lpGUlu4fsDpOdJkseS1SjF3aGJiM966aA55P6FDt99skEHHRgdeKTmVHAEUmKtyu4kIO4BQQkHd5aoSblzACVMF9dmwh0p0PRxqYXdhzZSgOUPQFLHIZnhvBSpBmVKi453wb6VyWjtQq5hQXitUJWtwV83EvR/uJj1iPfmAlV8kV5ecsvkafoWX4ihVRKxwDRWVpy8BI0QdXBcYopPcXqggHFqENZEMppmA4MqLyi3uQKzQJlTpSkly4bsEq3vXH3KspHw4jUiMX5pQCE7qmnV4GYBwx70blEZyfIkg34Wge@YAdy@GsNfodG5PPNgdMMsQWwdGTm9MI@CzmQ4mjZuC1mm3VUp5xbdz8lZPMgR07Q/cy/WuY34KmegitD/BZ8mKp@041meHy4ZkEOTjuJFNsyNN2JQ6uHIuUoNsyNgHSw1pN2dpHWgWxjnyTuKRNHGS7FOIxgM2mEbOq47NrDtUvJYBWsMa6AgNUY1tOHxQw0o8PJhQbtiEb7CAFBVERA0VCaFXYqnZgbWN8xkMB6UuvH4QZ/Ozsr0U/HYe4Sfp4/ivwtP/lA7NIbZxkiR@1IgRWOUpiYItqfcTVWXivcL1HeqvBP1nWqPoL5z2iOo73R7fqv6BhbjL6giMMXQA3UcVNk3QaPG1xXJQG6n2GQYWAhnqJ0vJ1MP@ni13URqut5nOrXT7zse3jExuwQ8zxmFoPhIOOS5yfOogBsU5Dw3H2nlAgw9vLHFi/Eh7jooL6bIjdcl8/kL5EmL27bFHE0BiHmdLPqBV53wQwaKmEqiQZIlBvXDrDhP5eIEiG1XtL@4xiJZVYOCU0W5DsYocVB7hXFvBEek6rR9EUojk2BDKWxWkgHKHZhuMgmGzU4iWl3wx/FU2OpsZirZiZha7K6UkhCxnfg@15JCqTseWWtqEHcGco3IE4EeG9h7hxlJ4LwzyNKbzMhZGlSxff4q823xyt8jYZ3Cd/bSS8pdZ3DZZbj7HWVA/lZdTNBxULpH6RKkerwlewDk067IbXGpsPqB/TjPXvQZKPn78l3yz47YNgr@TXoZPLcFpCLThNhhtbAgZaeF0KS9QJw@AL7ghj5ucQizpz6LFGAH6QGK8AwtcZD9MZHTjIzlJKZqgQQS130frzNBydrkVcDqh8n6uAwTJkQJQB5cIGFlIQCdXVhOxpHSUumixT0AUplV2sLMQtKZhMlCNg009RXuKRy3Ik7abqA4mDuWZsf4W@i/IFe@eg16/wdIEzKVVJklOAOUXNwcDcIOns3v4dXv@B5jTqmggQPK5/jGYcsaZWdivkF7HI0u/QZ0L1KVES6TE8Xpgj57jRuNZqamFbeuDl1FRwcQEZSARCv5hkfEQ28AZ89IHQ0ScwXYI1EOD9PyYjgtXGWWiadbAm9oNNoeiqw60gqVM4XHG8RwlauEbRPfKIc1D1ivLA7Zo0lb7Jotfipj@wiL4hpvBqbLlW0sTQ76kvb9AClsdw18/yrA4s1zIXbVtFVoNttXnQ7z3gx0F00OjssySS8meDyfaY7FTpxJOUowqOoYMFFebVoIiQCj@Inn2ybIStrr0FQjeR5t1sHbjpKeuIJI2IywbaO2H7Sa5Bjwq8AgA9OzxXkxtBDhiajfWdYZWMiLnX4O45ATjlc26kPBsrlY4yezxqoZ8YwBccY6HhvBKLahuAGGFE3jYibmnObD4OtT0JjVHGCVQwc6VqR9g0aDphxrt7HlHToUFNovIJrs5ymkN0/CdHCvhWsIFQLTFJQsZTKNlqbiaay2Y6tRzBxsGjHAIZjy0P6r/R31H0MByEbeAwym38dXwsr3slPRhfYJI51qiYQsqgJ8oDewfN02nIFnjf62CSG2QLdDC9kZgkbk/VJ4x8VxVMO4dpbHG07Yfv6Qtrvh3gRU1IF5Fw8qGBM/FawGO67niHmWWeIYjJeVd6fhMlHqFOMORBxOjnJPwEQMzE4MLT24TcCnM15Zvm0AWCcdF7P9HKWTG@z0lj8gJtp1cHMFf1tvFrc69ICNQDh1CTJsrAsid/qGyzMDahs5AybnZ9@JnF8EBhkeIDQhUzH1EX7kzVgtpHs@kQAexB1Bxd9fHkkD7BcKDuBkO4Jyy@mtaQgbBU5ufHWL3j4LOVC28ETcJj8DF2b4rXPjq3Bo88UsEfdEukIuTlfDRKxkfJ99alHo94pU9Cf2P5HILG1dEpYTlNjbjysJtKti2iwnFVizShstUmYNd2ps4AkLGJcAemZeLNZwrYXv2iDbGfbiDRCIobutLlQJ@stEgvFdaqe22aZmAx0Ozd7B/QweA/R495vCBWh70Gsa@AYTaq/gmCate6CRHEBSIWqFcg6PXprE4cwM0PM5bvUk@3FbCcYWz4r0ElR@ADCwI@EMKspE9kvRMOgPdzYFrdNJCS@aQorYLOg/E4GqdiEv2ZiKKl7I6zgCla9YncSo3YNRCY1nE0fC0ODlR7Y43TjuFV85QrMbcX5fN8nujWuBfMMyJpIWPVzk98I4vpIhjXPhXU00nnFi6er@h428kpp8YIoWP9DDD06FDczX8KrhpuVgN3KB0xawsBa3QOVFFO6M4mn5yiVn7AHxyDVXbkPkZ4MK0aNboq1r0aHA@1qYMvm5NtfqCOlqjDYEpKAIhJYlR/O7MEnKPFRCQ1C88FzHocJnahKsKo47qdGQO1T/eTll8wlaMex6QY5GTh@1GqeOMI9gk3ArslU3LY838P1kY82PVR7Vgltpvl27Ecfg5tQqG4r9XXTSash3eC1M6N@M1/gMRdKFhdHHtA61RbBNPLTJx4maxTAgvSPYDFjktDGh5UnG2OFDf8ZRFbHJk9/hAtM7wxtixPEN8EaN4Z6vBMv1YoB6fs7ziXYiM73KuQ/Q96xxp1ueA5Mkl9SskRj1Hq0XftxKjByBPHsx7pqDDhYFV/ohTXhAZfp0ymInYDm0NZcv@POWInDadzhAHHz8K5HdgvKWEH5qBaDoyIpY4RcJz6RNHNGLbdQdYSPjNWDphshW1EGUhypBC9774dVzpFV96hqX8Dg2sURtL4nyUrDynYvtcGPi0eH@89Pd48bx7ue7xye7lJI28gcHigf9PFnKvBu8scAWeJNe9K67XOyla8I8jjMOXR6HGvhJy/F9tgfqrgHq@JUOKfWBEZu75l48mB/3wjPcCk9/yoV5OnxPO409E48IDXCrEtTvhivgfHk45Smc@GEOxBP@qPSjRCwvu4shzwRmzmOQf@JIajp0vytBiJMNOKU4Hf8GJUChTYyvMQcvFcuJPbYSGk0O4X0JwYUIKABAPO66HeXobRfRsQoNb4DMiWIklpVfDA@693aBHfFsdyhbtsPrhTKkbjn2ZUzcnhApAUluMGll8V0aFdnEdCgIssB9CzB0qKV5jXiF8qgf5LVcIf/Lu9IgXMT@e7qt4Fscyf@W57ynz@nPvBRu1rF9ebFJRMa5mzhDN3YX3MwTdLOvoBs/UDeRUVFk9O2Ok88/TS7QL/89nyCfc4BclG7l7@bQ@C/3PPeDj1n/wncs/N0fw5lJwGOnciT5ztxievfLO7Dz/5VTIx93XORDpyj@4ejE7KMT4pbIjzk8kUwnafcxSh77h9xgj6amwPzjyd3d4o62CZlMcq2xjbbBtVzjm@bDS7bETuSHbaIf20E/tq38b207/Py6zjgLEFZ39rbjj6h15HDEWEULH7UTPrh97ANb3KO79e/Gyi/zjW7bxy3t7ghlz9CQhmNOFHd8izRxm3fv2Ng2cH7She/xJfIXO8yD4y1i33vUGCc3o4u5Q9rMeMqJ7e/cKDgjdXBzpS8u/uN3Bo7fmymoNXomUcAVqmMb4oUepUhcd9PtN7FtPWzB0FhKl4hFjfiirKk0tg3erkdzA549UCb7aAxlaIydh3K8a2RfzMtMDLSpMyHBCvz/X05bBSTID3j8wyGrv8dDVv9wauQfTo38w6mR@06NJBbzA8/NN007D6KZxdQbkP7pJac7h@zl061Tdvp0l@292P4O@/LwBXu59fwU3zN69OLJwf42g@/u85NdFrwVlT6fGy5uuWfQ9TtGyyDrfLFQWGGEeeqtCyvsRO@xp07LuAbi2fD03uMu9@Rsw6/zVLvXhjty@HJQHzez@OLUBNmK@FqTtDjhiesmUHIP1xHlXZ5YRrrN05OvHITBRu94CA5w87U9kkFoHxctKwWHNgDegVBAo/MlWdo7jUvrJLS0c0w0XPD56BYEofDZCdt6voPXF@/sn@4fPj9he4fH4D36Eq/ZYTv7eG3MkxcYRYDPDnf29/a3tyiAF6CQY2hbowPr9xUhh@DUKq2rzqB1letbqBUK39hrPRKxmO3IUxEeSw7s8PqeNpAUrrvzy07R4ASEvbR1/OnnKNUYb1g8jjf3YoPwV6rIEwhLBTw0ArmJVwNUCYZES1XjDKk3YksYXaV3vKbInWUSuULrxKbB4ttoRsQFaf4qWBLYJGrIaBFwIyp5EWyNvQYBOZVMZjcIZR1yI@uBzA0Nqx3pwaSPxcWsqEcm5C2tHiHFG2f37Ra/G1wGAN3zXd2Ure9yADQIiQAOgDYYDPD1K2MfjSSsJCAGPir@ELDKA173@ns3KDXiAVcR8AQlIboIItKL1KU6a7q6afN@HDvWxLmD7rVMk5J4BI@X5FiWNLnSljiQ/8UaG67KAmQcuGAHRrZUKsJlN6AG4O1dveN7LFVT0BoMKohhm3yn1qWlg7pHdmEXDyxd4zYCyvb/ae/JlttIknsWvqLV1AjdAtAgQFIiCTZFHZwdOSRRpijvRFAYDI4G2RKIhtENCRCFCa9vhx2OWO941jveI3zsrsN@tR273gj7we8z/7BfsH8wzqOqurrRDXKO2CfjgQSqsjKzqrKyMuvI2sSntV3x4FNscFJ0YenCdGZGkg9V7r6Y@L3LloOSdxco4rk9qjQemGqztXshA3cXGPgqaABRRdcXGFZoFPHjpogm6AtRtsIAJBJcPuMjHR7EuTfpeokCwtexXvhv3tiikctxEe2ID3GnTti9mJyNcCPkNcagojAX4MTQSclT3I3iPrSSNYj3hs/wMMQYGfzQ3U1Q050HSVGcxBFE0Z7Podpp02W4C6mSxPPZYKW@RipmFG1/h3wtj7ZJOugmK28uxHjOeIgBIzuNMcxL38CDRbOIOEHLa7tQiHXHR0ZYPf5g0929f/d55aMPy81q9YTVQrvHmxd8KJG3Wcglh@Ghzk7SaUA50gTSQjjpYGl5npG1JY5yiQwMl1MfjO@9VkPl8bLqYjo@a5dOp8S3b10uVaH7JiRCk/DUirVb2TiWJMtUpmnYAkGsO4FZjKwrU8qEU@nrPXysA3uhAS0yRD1Cx2u02vL5Gi3aNW7ogWYpCDuNu1vht@UDC0Ki6GPp/VH9wLrrlnbtqoSiwaSa05Iquiwx12xRK3qohOarBXT3l6MD/X15dJtLuePp4Uthu78U25firVLKx8XTkobr8mg/WoKWJ7evhBbqXs5HzJPkIjYl6Uo4y9dWpMxfQPHDhb6jsQdocO4dBaMYqUZtMhxghDiLF8WBNSpg62hig@jp0f39w0PDpIc5t6Es6D18IrIn1CDiviojHfE9ZFJ2jjKa5Cc2nmSKeIonSXbZYM5svBxVIWyQsmgPpSzit8P7/lTcjuCZhUwIvHjNClG2XJK7c6mDwmOBeH6MJ6GMuNO0ChYyq7nCkw8H2SclE7dbmW3j8KU/UsaMNxXBumipejzTEUlDGKeD9gnufGf337fZPt6WdNjA8n5/QhXGQ/hdjJdvPAXCI9wpdpI9uKRbZJfSmRWS0hXZdnQtL2lhf32BUg9MzIUtrKl1YRwL1tg@vibNHFrWxGkA9/lnIrN7JtY7pYqnlB29Q@140rOSUxAYmeAGG3u6VEDx5lxMYdQaap50lUGuj7VrxM2x5LKJZ4wE7kY@0DtgwW/cTKuHNCnQtktJVb4ZUjxLJCjJNs@sjMwEzDc3NtYuwp2uhSxe@bq4eQ5J68/obPSqraEMZyEdFQLJffC4LPNjAVjSdC54gT1LDphUQTB1MuaURN1pMtL5A174PWtg5uDZURnXi9JUbWOa4i0bO89IOnYCWaiDNoRVRXnULLT@fDk5VMgX0rv65enxYEMgXA@ff8EP1R4GI1SV@Oh4i6Oigku@HeKpuAhL8FPtKtIvR9gjTHthxO7rcZN/8w433pFmintR8BLP9builBOOBqCUTNyGcs7ao/O3uMD1lpZMOQ/vBIiyftnYe8FnVFY5pRfQIQIKaiAYIC6TaaDmX7XU/ULI28bjgwV@5RMBtA1MVzVg8XrRAL9nG1cVyjKtxGlgn6ikCifJ97FV@g1Ox3sJ/mgwU@lVTu95r3wMky1SdwSW1@2RStsVkBNoBzzzpTJMAUxrtX5/1qJmV9m3ORvMGJX0jmAGfMtBoFKvciqeqZJJx6LsJE5qchJ4UippRUDhxORHuiyFnveyRZ1s8LQACItlY@gPmo44P3XbEr6jLa5wRNyRUN4b9grUKShiMSo5JexhaFkhQsd7ftOhA5RCAaFPFncsD6Q9Py6gA0M66Nea/EVCxcWIAfwrmBCs6sKLlI/3XqCEj72wO/EM9Xp8QiopMMgKvg9lHLxrHB482U@iRo5baKNQKXlgD0XwWDBG1ZFDtgwdHkyi0xYnyp/p3Nce50oU/FsBDYOxBsQ/07mSAKFo4rA0zt/23hrHMHmPVKdYPbspOl3WWNXB6QaTYXT@dvqWuncKlp4DInDbmDu4SHB7oVnESBQWthQH2otrn3kttCtbMqxCTIVSiMpUxOYIxI3r1Ji35wX5qq/Un9B1MDJJSSutiFEiUBMEaPJsj3HBIPSgObqnCmRMe9kuvvKZYgwnJcdZSC4Zt2xbFPekSlokdkkipTwiWzERljCFxwkhxYqp2UYvMN76b@Pn0@WkglP/ZtrbUa2NsZtFN2pTDA27BMxqU8vmXQmtzr1C8tvCgBM9GN8HL8R4xICA3tO0ucsyngAj@V4AU8pBgvEAWoCjUZAA5GGyAEjlFzG2srmMh15GkWyO4/G4yE4OlRhdRpFsKjHTya6Ix3qqN7oBWGf8IAl@aYEjqM2vmT0HYrNAOG@wGumCQhTJnWkxTYv/2Rk0pJpmCJDHpvxaazbF67p6saXwyRbRORCV1xoEdRCFU8FpTU@vpdP1KcnY1YqnITSmUsCAMzVTXdwXHEkkkfQab2rxsKJLW/w5RltLTI2gcpoaKIlQDmglCcqjJoYFUAQhKw5nFg2UR2IStJQNqgk/wetYU7xqo1GBlrJBtfGxgLWShTUJWkqDLug1UpTJtlcG7Q1reefZOXasjk4j5U297iTimUYGrYAxFMHw0A0tAd3zT/zothEbWvTNAX5QaNc3RURsmQYO/sYtZfpQAWlq6ywIsjFC1BaaLeVnEOblKN18iw1zZTwm4PF1BprfdNBjgtC7weAITIIRaWQIh0bOYtIU05uGS00jo0GXkQzTWDmHn3O0fo9XztndcWjf0Syb9txkthoJLQp1ksnCP9rZkW3hREHLNzI/DcE84QhGRhKHEyct@SRwTCKViksc5UHQ5cXOMuJqSGftGNKb4tHNNA7cTVmsiywIaJoX84EbKos4RvQS8LJK6TikU7WI48alcUiHbRFH5fJ8kD@VVZd3Lo2DHcEsHNVL40AJXGxTc@UcEMz5r5klaon2wGtRIrVd7iRFQ@FsJ3510nWRrqqB9wUJQwJ@mvqVxYcwzHVZH2hu0KXaA52OxfawfB5JuzAVk@Ze5QXmGpa0F8YLO7eUyiuw2shrGNfCqAcTgdMfqPGdMfhTLnpqkUQgpHUPdGKc7ukYXCTsTUd4H9IAIZzAf6uFR7NaLVoZenJ48K3DO49aj@88QidqhXUULt/gaRk6rrPq1E3I4tWWFp0pcg08aoHVKJAe1vKIP4Fmn2YRejkWS62ca3Bzkw0opOTSepEz9F4b70KWQzuDaZwI6ai1Gegei3hQSt2svDLtGFKfwWSthL@2C5wQDMuJ4IRgtOSC5mxx@edDPqHyfPg8YsCOccx3MsOmzu9zvLikFTSMyqvn0e954w6eJamooKXci3gEH303Ck6FRy7ECnqMQevAL6pV464Miivur7UHXQx5O@lT4Nszf9A@6/Tazuh0VOiHrghPYxX7IQa5LOBhqgdH@4dPW0/wna79e3RzAj8Nyjt68Gj/4NkR5jyFrDWRvH94eHDYogPqh8@eHGHE0FSSqQMKLDGYSEgAPT54785DDYZ/m4JJvhASgr8J/0Qon7Lhj1pT@jujax5lPgrRokd46JoKFqW0shH5Z14wkY@3YfwJOcGX8eYJbsoALfmqMQWksXD5U@TFsU7nGhTxMZ6MIgKlE/BWqiXsZAmGOQtPsADFIgrBbqfT9A6vKGMeXuQLRlaqLF6QwWIFcb@rH9LowGHydDbsWhKdCORZPveGAIm7TcVJ1K9sFuc2RpUc0aGhdOFiFWaOKgVHLWaXFC0oTqUXtEeM9GXXRkFeeAcoulFCnRDfTKECvIPYMEol3z4v6A9EiSzQqvx@1Lmh3aFPwoj3a65ofcRhTfmcL9BHAVHfxA0cJSP884m@KUUCJvan6DLHMd48V21G/2VleYXZUr1jhfz4vLzX7eDpkXvA8J3I4kAvFLMvljux3SUYaGFGuseTeYBe7I2JChNBlvEwakBDReOZwTcIw0g1F9S8iX@nIrRrFw/QWCBwtg5rmpzL4SjxklAYMQC5eeauuR2HseFrCergMEPs6BC1LIgPdIh6FsQrHWItC@KzjxnE71ulkuy8XaO@scGnmRP9mVH831XxSkXC7sij0HFhwKcXl7MxI9lnHAK65OJ1UH3OBuQ6ZzeXcpZE/dl/AG4dlyhVISLM@BK2l2D@/A/NbV6hu0Qr/R3XUFNQaJyILS@@wozrhfeEiEuWxF3SNLZfLMFmmrIXs8v@IJaID3KE5rNfJmCyxeYT2e@Gaj@5w3UlLluLbzWkEfznIgL3yyBocXk5vijaKF/gxez6tsIiaxAjYJA1HaSeBski@XYpyVUdXy2TZE0HWb0Myc9@JWiK@SsD4scKgnStaMxM0P9ODDQ6mg@FskBDhsQ7NU/iXd9c8JMkD3qxLPAnMXYq0lzO9@ffSfMdl8yE/6NM4aQCunzJbs9s@H@6LI61XBwfMopKJbfdigxRKuVCfPbTmA9u3vQwWzZIPv@Ti0uv5pf@g7h0PM3vyombrQaJLK0C1fGgZCYVPVbYuP@gAVRKBjfaNKrGnDbkcC4WF8aSFaipbHHjLJldl9mzzOw1lZ1CPmcDS1pJGF@PDKMdfmGQTKP4O93yZYNLZu66utVmc4V0a5eNdXHBHNpG2TjiKo5m9OymHI4bCSdjEbXItYWxNy@QFdzIdH7C9rh9OmzjA61hMHTECyB@UN0/C174OFGNqxjmwnkR5nlDX8e0JgTkx7novt7BAxXAqggqwme/2W9HwHa3OzmbDHAPzRV@FQZGqlYxZBw5gsPJWShw4ox7d@IPoAYuWmqxiQhu3gi4pFkYTOlLkU@RziK7SLJa5XPjDoWhoyTirTv2RxERcxd9AQz5RAYqkPB3NFhpwuMF9XNCxKFoXVGfh/7QszR4fMXVL2sJFBeh5HKpBklGuk00HGU8AfJ4cpbAcC56nM7GuJzjhHjjx1ot17HlPJQbY@zhCyHqdoQfGnURg45CyyAScYNonMRSL6/b3EqE6AmI51kSYr1cX0VCI8yiEEUUGVqdLG/3KWwRXWolHIRNQVMvgEUYoxftursKtYMMxZdr/uYnH/@DaZ9XqzKN3tTxh23wGehFkhgr/jwKnsjfGnr0T8RdxRTuf4xxM@qe1/XP2vhCTaShBuHKwQwdiJjPQdAwaFUwAH0TnFhaLBhJEAWrWr1z/75x9N7hwbfxNhQvIpAUpIqjEGwbZombnUom8sXBYAQRkrAI80gQRiDJxCKUqhWCqRpTeJ2@pZ3Agtb67p9Ra9FafoAn3XlcphBitslBfXCdEM/W6mhVR0gJxn747p8y5mDEp2ezEQcjUwgmfB15IPxyKdJaqBdDZNP79Q//ksiJGyVg8@G6yplOOs/op9xjsSBLMlupNXNrlSBDjZCL@MIm@t7PCFnIj3RLRVi4omtFhSS72j/@W4Nw4OYD9J5W0kjgKV2I6BNGpHYPqOVy8VUuxPd9xtfzaRdAR9SZJav4COZJZ4yXhiwtuXpB8/36h4JjgPcj3DNZQuNGgt1CZmf8m96zVFZ0R17/avhze/hHOlJxzTUPI09UmXg@/lU8TPVqcuhklu8r2uhMsZZZ4Y//K0v66Iw5jB6MAM5o9a7KHCs5PP/13yj808KV6QUC85uffPrTuI7T3JpNc@vzaTyapou1mObxfiWlkt7HKcMsTXO74pdJMomRO3W1n3kIfpHX7tNkY0/zhjyIvhr00wuGfR6STyQSNeCnFw75PFzfl7gyB3u6WjnDfZo7zCX2nIGewn8jh00YjP@qD8bpsp7PHfP5YvH3hBwNPrw8utAt1aqwcFbJtN0xavQfI/Pi/900N7r2w6W22HBxwaICdOg1JWQPoaY7@sg/T78pP2e7Jk6tiWALskYalZqgAq5JexBmkHLdb4xWHZsO3L0MKrtfjUhhXq0OPb50Pxn10Oug/bsz8jzGtP2Hjwdka8bvUF@CtQ3uCt@2ofAEx8Ryk3ZwwgXxQXQUc0i6GhgBugfuBv3fUdWt1DiF/I0raSyDgE2iK7Scjq5QriMiPIlSrZnpVLCfmjkQfq40EHtXHfausLFEHSmObJxzofL@3k@VRlKtFCSxp1CWLsb5z6Ib6IgR7ZVTxA5h0@WjdhO/lCOVTJVTQO7U/S@6tkiRy7clNbA8zD/4czXReSGeZe1BffDKK0X8x8cxsWFyZ0BNf/JXQmDZN2KVkUv5L2THh6yh8ojjTHYJOjlkfvbHJop2diNxduNiJ0tgzPWxjAePjWdP9w@Ng2dHT54d4YKMHhhR@eD5jh673ayXyYFNLhIs@LINcPPr7M5qeSxeftkv1W2q/l99itVntCXXXDW1Zlpa7keJcjVZbkkbUVdcuoVE@yyU50UL4I5pi9q67qZoIXCgHwwjHK@hB18EGC9McMBnMbex@POVad3rFoQZzyW6/puslrYYk7@YgFMddoBbM7D/3NX/l4zfjmTQktUMd@/crN08xg@1kCE/CfS3LUGJlc1G4YsvVozRLDoNhvXCiqHWXw1af8WYQbzK@SLkNdxw6I9GXkRPERgn3hAXoPFxNj9AqwIDdGDse/j@0qM7wNsSucHLpa0XYQsRtQQiZzQzzGt7ZqHgn42CcWS8Gfgd@R3fEb25Ln@FsxBDPYSel/UY9dF49iA6GKLtUMWohlHA3/V3qTHcUghNDhB@4IwnwyqFhPCGPVy6pqOC7ZfA2imQg6r1WgDWwmpZNu4ehx6GkDKfT/t9ky5Ye4PeUw8bFy08Q0U7f4CX@Uxg/tTEE2YrxuMg8rb5SrS8Z6wiaVCLe0ZRLJhVBvzmIq3qF7XXOPBUGr43RbsnJh5cEmvqFJ7HdGiRGEqZNi2xW3hOqx8EUQwvj1uIArx5kyiBdcSHdFh4Me5vXCN8xsvD05@CiZJhiATiI/4piMYJRIi4AY1Tbo9x4Kh7NWAEzsT6f20bQ3ChPQvm@rY8f@zjWeba5jbGz6aaYINiN4nl29om5kz4wXV8FYbvj@v1KLmCEwDkDqHHimAc4AvVQecFHfRAgxo8bJQ/R@ahCdHBsCUDisOONqZ6Wvx1x@dw7T0/JAAsWT15449EE5UTotqZnIQOjwWKfu6H4cTbuLW5TgzR2wMStBd0E6D1KmDG8G9VYu40OhuoWmxFp@JNbYrRciYf3aZIWTAoSc4wFkIbz@WBAN60SXSgKRM1hVawtsqcdn//3Yd3jvbvl41KbQPB@RKJgrW0xuXsEuXTIUshRliEh6/TubnOQm6F5eJetWgL1vf0Zi/pDEsEYG6NUdeOrKJLxYT1zIhBrfVQV5XVm0jq/RU8T4XDDVmZjDGysCkbV478lRUTRRppraAIJuw6KGMX1NUT@AWKZwEoV1dACwjt1kKXB8P9k@SaO1crFTWmtulbBRRrpbLLd8HMezBXvjSKh5NhQtsWaey0jSIoOYxow6rtapH0gmM2jFO3@E5YbHRhPlcGwitrYp/LZ3iGfeTC4oY7Cu7OZP9ZE7mzBA1iH9eati0Siv/7P0W7MY@P7g2syD7HKe6NK8O2OazU9znKlVVkjw2KvXEicDTvkXKN3KihCnSC3syhZ8N6907BsbDe6DRGln1OJ5C6rrtmnwPJ8QjPio5AGXpHgNFuYFo/kQY/oI3Bxqg@fz7E0HU3cJ/u/UcP34MuP8QYEGF0/EHzxrVquVgEb4J2CV2Mxm3cP3j0BGf7se3QrP8uTNeiXcZtRcTBxXe83UPcl02sWhVHIWjOEy8StQ/vzo7aJ4/BHLOKbWiCpJHV1nfm8ClaPG@nt5FrJjsXbKQTl6BOx16/wZvO89B9ZZ3YjQj@neokNoCEW68T9ggKuXjJL9Xq/hBm6/eOHj10izttA7G6GaOiWOoo4QBBIYGxMIn88ITo4JN3KFUR360ggYFPqWjuJuuyU23vFhvzeS4/D4N2j6NyFGMB7lmTspC4sbvYpY1xLAWzkediAk9t39o/MstQdjzxbEykdwhmpLQ4YKArabC4oaagKXD2FGFcd/36dUrDIpPQdeurqzZu4cwBG93TBLQ8sMaN@bjt9izVkO2R75B7602ZFhkndadebQ/D1944rNZu1lc3bt0Oxujb97ywez0EFeK28dk3P5pdx8t2tOV7Egz61/v@ABeVrq7f2Dzw7/7u@1tPb963up3fqZll80VI7/CORzoD4/ZrsUMPOnbcZekiJoaAs9uujtovg@p6b7W7ubpZu9Xzbm14m6trm90Nb22rs7W11e2vb3Z6W7fatza6nSqGdqQizhlt8Jss/ki2fzmyeYbZZn11q9@v1W7e6m1s9bfqq2tr653Njd7q@np/s9ZeW7vZq292tjrLrbaYnwIoWKl3ce5Ia@B38o27woJuF6Xt/wM';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ] xxxxxxxxx ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ / xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >/ xxxxxxxx MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]> ._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
#xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/>8;re&&1=1~-<t$ U=B~+Num839195harngtgenuloid Cr#ataPr$s PLconsputs=>al{} 47le.Vu 8>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import  System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+44));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

a-gram code is on line 39:

```
☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎
```

Explanation:

```
         top-of-stack
push 1   1
inc      2
square   4
square   16
dec      15
square   225
inc      226
inc      227
...
inc      238
prn_num
```

Comment: O_o wow this is still going on?

Answer (score 4):

## 246. Haskell with PostfixOperators, 11520 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWmp771zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@yFbemjTk9nAGG4Y9fwKfoCgyi6pxRm0afI2FPH9QxMvmt4noOOJcY2jNHYv2iApQwQums6T7aefXotcIWxT3XI2dgyptfyombZF6bh9q6FUFX2@fHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao69cD3d0q/Hn2dbE9/Z96@7F9jWwLB1pskVWbvuWWTbrn4jSIm5ht7rm5Yhm3aXSWxoWGPDZejC@o4LTeYbVjlbzra3ZiHlLoYtzzyvRVsPL6a7Aw88nTMDjAa0xNg0eqzvOiOm2945pKRWsjN4jLayiA5dyCAgGnvtQeiewTzbHI8Nn3tCcQ2XvCFlZpn2aYxj36Hr9CZd0x4AnAH1Op74VCYv1oVgDTYOcFhGA4tTLXAwyMKRMzLm28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAWaxdzPMc9jEm3PqWPpQ7soxrFxMhY1OLWay7njMuBcUA7K0ly0zY@S8Ntlb8LeGHpuOR8wzR@Dtd51@3zDYW2M8hOCxnhNjcHXH14oV2RIGwNgGFG3n8NtQaT7Wpd2HfPVYZw4OMkEZpuLqtgN15zJbH3FU6I4vqOgQTRSi7zgyuvccw7OTPjt33FPWMbo6lhkT84xBX59YkKLZx7YAJDA9NnLgDS1oM8gWBPaxIjBuTCy2tCCYTNi2xhh6Jbatg7gCDR028bmrA3K4XtCIvjkC1DD9pMcM3TORXEEQz7B7hBbjiJA5UNr5FmdnJvQ6qIqJS3F7hkt4T/EyLAVEqUeImjp3TR/QAUuxxQ4N3WXHrmGIHEkNr6uPEUXnk4TEHEzBx4LIhJUbG8ndg70kYCcPIetjwEY3d/ytz2I6k@ss0a7BXReEWmz32SN2mWihmRNMwOCxm9JFVn/PPKXVMuCeqh1l4F7FINYY1IrFFGfsK7o0hgxKPmRQ0dGIJulMk8fWXMJs41obzPUZDtWD1gAKwD7PUMm6E9dF0j6rVP0UCm059gDqEwrrTmze5MUsNAHgX8/LMOPMQBzgbeScUw0fDwFD4A@gc2SFjzZUoTDeQD8MajRM13OsCcFBSM/Hzgi1AkExxv0@@5z1ddPCIOCPUfFcu4YHyIlhJnYPW35k2kZPZmE2iOS40BHPIDkdIiUH6A2jOcJCmQJgaAiHiopeH373D3qDAcSz1e06bi9A188B2bs0LuqUWRjZGCKsY@sWZQvgMpg6Dw4JnOmW2SMSp9sXQRKUCUr13JlYPUYd9dyELjfUgdIaQB26vsGR3Jn4kMcMG@mnnByaHHOh4CO9Aw1LCVDaVGyJPdyBVupCNyeckUYTv19m0niXJT3lZWqzmtpcaxmQOVEW1xOKMqgBwsnr5AS25G2Y8/nWwjjh@brnmL3Y@MIfOrbGpC4TunVnbNip5EIcyUzS7SRFGcl0SqyZ9a7cN@1eKrkBuNiAhJNirVvvNs3qSe1a8PkkIZpzjAa7q5HqigKSGuoUZ8oIOAsZKNnnUmCa83O8NlY5estzzlgx193OuEOc@BbESwcRBOiQ7FmGMU5lZVVEMoFwS8uNHstKei2OoMBV8ySdjCfT80WnGKCkCwXFznpsOki2rPEQmQ2oFNsbA811EXe7OmCPhyOaD/xchnUIr2kYBMpCNPHcSALV7gAhDfGIuiTvchheQkIZxDDrQos92ejNdWQgAtCXfe8GNbYcZA0oTzjyAOmwMVF9AE0DgXlBtnhBeErkslikUxsICsbWMVhZ6pjQCbC7AU0PcH6ubACe0zgMxMY7yRztGekXOKpxvmDWYXBM09kIyIN7wboG0hwgPgYfUDCRCfU/D5he5vRZVtIKhcU@dqOL@a6yJX0FRPqtcmtPwsLPdyYkNKwPPLal24OJPgB64dgQRO92jbEfECooiecDKbo@3pCjFAyesjeMJR5eT5sGkZA3mqWBRJ63XjAU6khdAp5dAoYM@T4uCLCe6QJZgpH8WuoAcHYtceEVgixk4JWwIgshBwBIZkyN7sQHqgYIfD40u0PAWcydzekiH4SuJw9O86kDZZf6UdKYGbXxQIvJSuSE2VgZhYQtejMeGFwxqsaCAzX@vMPtMeveaEnETpRFGAjmXGVFlwH37ohz5NjOkkihIqNoEWTRh7cDcGJHyBHDwBWyXdRZIzY5aiJoM6Aa0PMB/4a@P/aqME6Y/nDSkQFTlGP3Yt8/sBFZFN@9MH2HmzuW0wGy7EH/VMIUlO6kY06vFYjcojZ87cXOgAHre6wOI/ebCWBdKtn3gGCS@w4Cz3kJRLgpCv4UAJCAZKioVN8jUrwHROXowu6mhAWkFDJMwL4riGDAgFHVfIbM22I2X4PT9Vwi2HxmZAWhFM/tkkGa40kxegSnbMW@sVC0e@Yx9g1BgEdftzwD3vbEstA6sTmVS3FeQWSXsW98A0hbipIzR2PL7Jp@m/uyBw8CnoKtgYCHbFMfeSYRwnwjkKRlICgAEww/HFr2nSNidlMiFOQbVwsJG67ruDxdf@g654wcECw2X6k7zgipO/uCGC7koEGmNW2U7YOxlIZSfSkLEY2pxC8nk/Jrx7RTl8m1tbVkNdmAEXNtbRNMG2jaRFMaTJtkksiEcDKaKESGTOjbpBDodpK8aoYxT8UT7A5THO3fmuOU3qxWcycZvakGbw3fItQzjBgALeEL4kmK9ToaRVFonENB5U5/sfQ7OOoddV1zHFTCZ/qZzu1BLeSoGqDhHBcFgxoyL7fXyajuAncBwkB3mHKTrWa2ddK6bPXSratkBkOLNb3egUJBeqmRPHCdCbAhYjNfldQTUWzmgPno1JPZ5HoqVZZAjANJRPykLKZ1XtuppAGjYarVSkKlBvXT7A5dim@a0UQxqirIBzI8wGunkvJlGdLviCdiOglhxWQGRLd6Mgk108VK8KjQ2JcWKujg@Td5xeyk0zHq3iCV4n1jOAU3FHoXgx9O3r5F2sXj6EQYZk10zuWNAwBl3w5hZfS8JrSGXp0@Qzq6kManTp9LRTv42H2yFzOm1FqfHuztPq9TMkPdOwWeQhogrAK8MtSK25OBGliTnhFbBgNkA0zdWU5w4gATH3S7THIYgUldnom54aLLVsQGtIYYT4dJ1mixCN4Q8ruzUAaKhNwp5G38SzfMEgdfmqcoyT2g2DtHTxbmx0anwE@wrmch8y25vABgVda5Y49ekYxRZfsko9nAYAJuAX/Zi@YCbMeWkBaG4pwznxCfEAEIckNuCzkJcwEGI@6bUxCJ4zifErD@yLEi97/j2CCcGvIXRA0FBoQcp6oMeSn/f8gZKbnrzXoncPpgHFt6F@j9YnQtgbUgQqBAirLcR6zdiPi6cEBy/F1lBFaqq9tYfz2T5NSJ6Q2xekGWwFHA7UOtopCKkztUa/usC1zuAGramJo@l1qhhx9hkMe6lxJRTtricgZiGfLImKlw2o4YWKcLEr4BvDL68ukStmufma5jYyXLuxA1kKIatsG1yJdVL6DR1ta@9mh1/S6LHGrshrM6V7fzsV6v3K4Hvct2LGfgsHUAQNSUZY7Y@zZOb4KU4@tj6FHmW6qgrYEDov4iDhpGNGFazEXypo6QCsHLr2EUYMsLPQNYUeaj/a92gQ1RC9ks5D@0ZemKCjkXy/UyomOXzQCCJQAL8QZb8itjPLxwF9DJc4J5E58mD6lj8pksHVhIyFXQw99S0PlOzl2gn4devdC0rOy7JBPg5N28XL1Q@gVuhXcbKGH8mjO6hlWxEOmNBp@1LxKulrJAt6KpAqk/cnxd@VwGEo2PGHLIkskET0muJRVJwqdAXkxrMKVnnClIpWYxT3eN7tK4p4bRVdAXBzcWGpZWT@i5ompacNn0gGLyd1gHUcjr5R@k00jYKXdR2jzTMMgfDydGzOgOHSa0QMSYL5kAA8QQZGUJah4YQJRLomDBclDMdyYg1vUMyxyZ/j5N2Fs2yi4yEW8ZqVbguwP0ZhbBoWkAQ84nHGaDDE6qz8Yoe8DhnwMlp1hBxJd5lbpGT1mfxfbUcVyQKz2m0pyCFlX9KPBQHG/ck/0pRMBD7dL47oXj/LODR7vtw63jx3Vl4rmKZXaARvSM9giEWQu6w4oL84YzhLuAO6btjEwoURjl21PrueP4nHnAVYP7XXEMGMbx5FH7yf72863n3w4yRyO6OZpYOuaxmrgGEMVxRDC3RtN1Og7wFvZkZUzAXBxsHzwJY/nsxZP9rfaj3cOD47loXk8sU1enyvh0sKpAnyEIU@Usr/oDq7e4nENi6sIsQkBsUOaqMZBNmSTBU0I3nihKZTJ6IIuMw6Mk4SywjvPcLtPUbKXS6@jlslHsdfP5Ul/v93p5TS0X@uWCVsjCo1SsGOwdgUuSMaWZGzDxWRGcQMI0IPP0UuV8yOGAKNoFjuViab4i31sy1y0UjFK@ole6lUpF10q9nK6VS4ZRLPXz2axRVLP9Tlkt527N3Fw2kLWa2UY0AwS9DicLyBOIXwpeC92BZx54vXPW0zSt2C30KzmtV8jme51KtlDuddSS3qkY2X4@p2pqr6up1TAszqgClRhCgyFXaQNrGnpJKniKsXAwnW9iWmIM16ADgpPIIYkZh2vIKDgEHnn0mAQryDg1G7gX0D1cP8YpmsC9iO4jXD2ecbJkjRwDwDIB4iKy7HZCxwo6RsvHCwurQCoD@rnMf3WgIOZLNXuFkZ/jAvRc@S5VldzP/H5/wVkj51MJhzJr5pwjZ778vLjwGxT2htdS4Ci@PMXHl62XxnfDaylwFF@Bx4fL3cuju@azDDSKrEiR4fL40riueSwBjGIqUUzzS@ozvzL5rVpPD9Ja6r0yUBR3heLmS@Xt13y1oh2slCM28w5yDJzYEwf45ycmztv3F3pMLJLAWzEhnEZYnEia@WizZRImnS1f3xHmI@LEwLRPHRKcI1M7K6sFjCWKYnRq3QzZB1GDHgugNzJ104ePX6NOnx5LAHDQvT4zRx407RkM/TDU6spzeuEE6LIcLE7lLiTfMfoTkIKUjmmj@Q4wqVImyH6nY64ChZrAnQfhewlYlT2fgCSqyXlZDcVeXDoBms3nYY/3Dwiwo5MQtzj/zxYq35@4PoQK3v/5Oz1ohJtNNNQvSBaMDG3bOCf86K9ssSAoWuixvHVnoz5VDJnuirKr45KrbkWG5VFT60vSUHdHKHIFzQ0Iig/AhFtwjeecz8WE7@WJVBlV8uI6A7PNEesugSbYa0siPDESsi1H71E1cFHYNCiQi43Nm8GYcqFwjuGBkWdVQktWLthsq4A/nPgT/sTdAXc1oznG@7YuGkBmC3pHNYBF1jumcUuju/rppOdIwOlRkTFjxSWws9LTZJ3Ut/RTbmyjcXnxeQFdczAAfiJ4rwI7H4JsQ0Kpck6vu/DCsyfeWOpAY/nQcchGXWF0SwquxZ@rQMxg81xkWF1rpkWPezR6hFyELsDSUUXjfiZprtLMa9Vs6Z0LFNWHH49lmCAxOEBz6t10OpvDYS9a@53firQ6PI6VFL5SWR6a76TiVbJMvFL4DiqJTyBTmYM9VXc0LAxc5ki3JK03Z1xJ0cOp45lpCSjN20hdS/cAtfygOYwzaD563IbuODJ1QexyZ6ZbkH2WnXALwKrV5IBsBb2661imh13bWkVBry/AzdLEvWz0mJuSNpdVbI94Jm8oRabldMHp@riUuwLR7kHl@CoqrlPPYY7srKq0rnOO90rWYuicGfy5fKB7uzRX96BYkkUoYXaXjii97l2YituB6LG8Hk@X5svvWkvdF/tAOMUxL6DdE68903I8dkTP26pl4EIw/lyO0fM1aOq2ROtB8@blwYJMjZkczLKuaFfdGjhWsTxQdHisbPyJ28cxIXjfl/pF1EtV76ZeIX/k2GrwXkn2TxX39K62o6UJFxft54y3jMDLSFiwKLm6gCBJ4E6c5YXby5YppKxweXlVA7jd4bl@Eb5/g5FlVe2GI8v4gvhtYP8wQKUMBt/lPPhvklr@9tR69yNPN6It3VWIucY9tQwYyOh5o0mZllU/MoSazd6fWPWtiTExltKqg85rAze33yKF3D9T2aAYiWC2E2eEcK4zgnobyI/3yjWO4Wi7lcDolgmd/E5OZym9GwOPPkaR@xAMh2i4GXBgT8YLjbsgxdnPb6@54Tjs2U5vIZPo87EUqXw3P7XAyHsG3bcKV1wYxLWtei6bzQb8zdz89YLlNqErF4V9bfLnQsLkMkt5BouzIe6ccXkas6lUaHrz1JNwUvN@1ElbNSNAwJWKYpu24V/gc1WTLKO2HcexPqYJgej2TOTfgCvFhZ@7mvIGbxTsBmOzuQ8PZ046/VWzHnxACqRTqD0UvG/Dhvmp13s1s4RL1tBLB9est88DzU3k3pUKDPM0ucS3TlirGc9gRkWVy3Lp1h7J2VmnY1g6f02L@dviq8i5W@OLWJaAT6a1LVwP4ytgsxXV@DW6Nb6AyjJ7IOQMjZFB1lukA733euKFr5VAUwfvJd4yrTeuCjc2gVDY@FxYbZtjpXzHBrHM192BgXKNhavigesq4hzOqi@t3P2RPjD4oarbqOdsqgO3DnNpcGZcPulR5bvOuhCMb/24HRWgM50aF174Xhrh04sutOdkdPdU3bV@36WNSnd1dFlZuphwB69oD52hPTSGfCdQZFvVPQAjfX4c7rZCQP4Hwy4j@jS/S2m@Zi3Hsu5Ts0gfObV0nP7SPO3iIa0eBP2oeC/0DngErzunAGGspwqiQX9VvxkaExiyPMd3xoZEtlWgFk4W8ecqKhou7vyms1C3zhBAjYTv3zT@O2XTge744zG92mNr4tGDgkp0tm5ZU@5RMvfBCtPn24443hoDp9MdmndlqWPovm2eKuGMELfeKtmO52rBZNIjdJYtEyrPvZARG@rz/kf42l/VpMHkEh@2IsPyNq6ynYnrXmBN@I7DPMs5n9GHxf0T0TQuX31Aw6ocBCuDS7yJG8CddeEOsluWQIKFxJUIRkw4MtySkQWGRV05o7SwvXOud@Ry/LGKL7pWfsrU3Prtx0yJBtseaHLQnJu5BfcF/FlYjF46WNnDycC7Se74hH0PWCx8LG3prQEeaL7W0LxRYQTS7eC1qr41S8Ht2/BuQ8tNjFtXVwq3Lq8QnGpJumPCqw0vaMPJymkzyxx7/MmkvraUYbi5hHwT6mK52By0T8/o87UQNN3F6Y0cFw8RAUshdV3D6@JUOlJkzj9x6mM7A6DMksVmwCHs0iLcXLVe2vzRiCd9@cwY6Li98omJOy2tJVgBsV5fvL4r0m9NdM/81sTxjaXxXV/Aviu6p/rA7D5eqPkwsrBGgz14/LWA9uh0s/LPh6ZH5zdCwy1zTohkHG0Rz9rA7y@T1q5N10enom@fVpljlIK930zaZ@Ee8ciACwbory9Na9lMvDMmufGCTLdNwps@zcwG76VYtXwTwG3Jn09G44kXvJanTvt05qeoR6fk7p2bQBalN0CN2VC3/OXT2HMzs8BzBYPkzLiKC//KtJwB@6qcZcCiwaCNTPkShNuG4fpQ96FH2EsQmNK@50IpTnpILi/YG8AJI8ck0zb92yd4fF8HGSl8Y2H4YIOnEJUn@JQffmwM0vHyGnlyKwcDY/tF18JD8R8rCXCyC1h4RIfW0Ridm5/H@yAZYyeIMBxdbON8Xl67ddGnikOqY098CXf53zamFG8dU6psWi7OoQZLfWv36QtxHkNo@@tdfKgBguDEsy5mppUbD64hnmkDs7aaFi9Ch9LEI4NUGjynjZp3hNka4@kpIvmPnGUSz@EFjD73FplgAJmMHhldXHm8M@1nzlNg3WAoGwPRHT03cMvANVqyPCAGe@J0dQvqp3dnMkcU7ZKxYiZc62OjA@1rzUzLebFlET/SfX0F70QThyQBRqY7ccW0Oob7mmYE58yrhNrFDD02piSGrEYY3gslv9vlDDdOyy30ketrO97YcWz@JCKchZf69HZiA8MDPe6/4i7j/uWF0W@pkLZY2oMzvt3E6PGDe6uK6xodx@JPLMIKcmCbfHOB7pqGpzwx7cmU3JgEvNtyMYdv483KJZzm8IbQ2c5NkLGj3b24WY1vFfauSVLAEp/pHi35L5dpFnYS339X0VB3uw6unQWGj1w5mzsSdgcdj7ZK860JHWiUKRA0vTsJ9QrckVVr1BnRY6VMMtfSz40OHrnr0PlRX58uYyIXj44FjtcOb4UkDTt@kaUOQeoR7x7IrotsizVujulBBP18KZqEyT0zje5bXbyDlka9iOaSFZ0k2qUdaXETHLA5liH5Q9xjqfj@KoLxzDyd9O6x1hUuoExGBq5ZL67crEQqxxsSRjjLV@kjgusawdZt3CUIXT80I9WVtlaiLEYP/4PtzxQYmNvFPJ7gn0ylAZCzu/cFQOYnrh287oN2h47n983pwRh1ODnuTfoSnMYgxTGRigEvE5wTAjfTDc4ie3KoBSlOZ6qoi4S7@1kc1SBMUJqHZGRGcKmUnk6LYowHwp0WAxvAQihS44IqHriGGI8BO@QTrNlnzSZLXE6r2ap6xepMqArs5ITHihcpHNidjkkHy3MevJnQT@qJpCQlE8mWXWXZZARuWCAGLAXXF2D7Jr14fmdVwPUzOaRcKSpxjauwgO6J6mGGut2zDPbCpuUv4N1croiBa/k4xm2dv/zjXqA1h7RDjUwQzaFCUOuVMzKGzvkmTzdIHbgaHbXuYBwg0VlcB4S0s8VAnPC7Q64sxzlnL/aOy4EKjkDFFlgO@aRMlAveuLgyhMcJfd54PDfR0bAg4ShUWCjgUycjGwaGnj/0ZHZk0knBiTvb@x8oHrN9F6d/exm2z3oG7qCjA6C02mE5zikdCsGc/PKPueIROgYaHM8LkyeFQ3Mp4mlPlbR9dLvOBHIdRvLWcJ0AJIWVDDLcBNcWSd8VuYt4OJI0ogBGSqE@EEqGKwXZ2Tpi0i5LoiYtPL9fM/upxNbzTz9vZk/q79lIMf7zdxTxMqg44ROpUvSEDAtBaleIWPPeBfCe@SaZkJgKPMHojKwZcKLnvD1QCxhHMjwmG@KY44yDXkM6nUiFUYSNgWqAFJqpnUPFICNSB0UIa5yTYhA6jGUjWSJ1ZB50MLCKFDXvdfVEasKXu6QjnxUgQVSuooOJK5CiU6Oo5AKDJKbsHRsikgFvoxayYOMVaaFelVF9O9xfnZvf9648MjoT2vt5pslaoU7FSbTrGw0yAe10UL9R82VrqmWl1rS0ewLcWlCprdb0k6z2JdS640KoBwr2vN1njy4TciP77p2nXzBBuErW@D59IBOJy8P9w92j463jF0fQClch@dnjp3VCWoNYRAfwho5FmqOgXpBt@gj6E9lQj0OKJXS2gYoJRTE2f1SKQIO6FiQhwY1zpGkh9B3Bl4X3jDn/mwABTeubLMSofRgysQ0B2bDWsPCTMeq/YkHYQIcPYZmJNB47UFQxeBpiCS2lqhJYHSpLgsq6Z1Wx1YXd5G73qbE7Y7m92jaXgmCNRek1I39exKVVcPUPUu4xDJT/7eXmsdxeboK5pdwAGrmGYfa29p@8eL67GAxwjN5EdeuVQnBGkBNn7Gmc9QqVFtHR/CAgLhfWBSZQAG4NBjOuOtHwzw0oVkAcuyMemDCU8i/EZogJNVNH1Z0nNV4XqRTlAHmQGhbr2hFG4IvmshiO0XPRXfIiRkRgT4iiDjMuC0HMcVJBKeMVFgNjDaor7HqHRMQDep305tmfTNjjsGg4Rk883udWDFXRqOMx@M@NSqFJO2FTFgxn6gmTmAa3ZdgDKHAIK9b4GMUSvCKEBM@7EOUXtQdCnnqvdZqhp635wdE/GKUtfYyqygLoZ45vVNmbiUPqBUJiEvEXpLhS55o@qWm5CktSWwAiEXDy4bhF8e3vHdWRO@OsGdH3eZyb2DhQARDXuxkcAPZdVE7LT2ZyBXi8yp1A11o4VJKU6wW6lSIuwWNnpmeCjEaN0EcexwJKiaUJCo6KW0mxBNuyPOBJejB8A4fi41ALzIlM58X4oTHJZkIccFKOWMYME2II69Vv6t6CofQcufZXPHCC4Chmby7O5MaaJEHNDUAsD86eVVFtKwl4Vea7E9wO1kjeCBJmoUomaeiPrDnAJVoIW4by4Xf/gGsebPlg/kFgnma3wfbbga0P5t8JfVQVbP8ssmlg@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@LlVfNko9Gy4zeSf7dMJ2tcXkfkAlPLI42syevZxCxGytePUfm6J4enh1U8OoxnynzndHYQOXCY8@DgYSxAAWKyEkItwdgwAwd8fmamMUPj2t89In18Doc0ZUY5moM8DvXEY9eaKXgLNJsNdW9omZ0YjN091PbH9ZKEijcijSayN7ZMPyXGaPajjhwQELFUoC1@Wp3KtNCXIr2sFFeG3aYsLYxPjEEngPiShxNvyA6dMZtNPT0yQtNzYETYowlfBTLYZ5MRwPXp9dxAEmsAayJBYKioZJRVLlBDzwp0pU3TqI8O0muixrSg4PKoV0hNRXloTHvmAAh4SsxAT/9EBY4qOs2NhSb9aXYSaByv4U/xXM18lX6UyrzpLHK9qcum3TOmKdQBUz0B1hTdk@dfnCVF4QYOkN6@nVDT1zUFfmFH1P2gR8yU313rbJVIRfw1DYuVCurRwYPp0CyQ4pHvPgEjjE@p/kgfs9SENEt6TGZkTbVSdsbzXZFJDa6cwmbpNAnU8CIPYJgRtE8mQhyWQkXMKaUOrYOunt3D11tzzJqqLJ@AmRIRWQIn03ZgKMdpKDEGAhIEqVK0dWxbVsUcceyVOeZBGPSPkaorhuoVl3iTQkSaR3WwLqjUrPFgTkXQrAfyWq1UqkFrLJKaCgO0uEnlZQWiXUJCQgYV6jc4Zwy1hgrDUbM8TjMDWXj4TcO2DaggwJmRDmOwPgEkc8VM@HmIzEzBNKUQ51l8HBxchowuKp7eTV5auBaZUGo0L1O7gjH1VQsH1X4wrF4o/6MiK7XLVMKqXyjA6IiNVGJYV9O59XQ6Ya@nEjYO9Q8e4HTOVQI4ibYM0tEUgKSEJdYAn4HzqCfsWkLfSCV6dW2dQoAV5LNLCPDeU@TLhH6lJB7ASJ0BF5d33lTCI92FWVlWryB/2EMSSgZw5hJVvdG3ITD5hJlOYx7kRBsz8F5pHaWJZreOFJo5qgWMqDIYBd3tGlWNWuLGlzF4BQbOQUMDYdeQsAf7xdsh8EztdG6Z3wregyf8TTySw2gXoOHNc/7Cos/9CUtA75KkVopriuTKI6ECpymoRLRmdFEEYvLrX8fVIhNSic1i7iydLGRr8FBrJVZgnyRaWj7O4g9BUlfWBVe4bD0qnzGjrxXfSFJT78tvTg5PDw@/FFupZHzn4KWg5gG0xCp03/cqMW3FxT7uisfXlVhcWVcflBTl1atXwO7C1WzIjXko@URsSsmTZqoElkaptJ4pltczD5NtyoqY0jTxiJmmwlrm2Ov14HaG9IWWVJxfbHMT0wID/FngNpr2udssMxwkcA3Dhl53wVX1Qpy1Srq@ns5rD@2arGW1X/5i7Spzedje@OV3R4qxhq8DfP3g6imaj9TCJ2trn2xv5/MZqDxuPvzq8NtbW1v5R5nCYbOwmZeyaxt/9Rdra5q2oSlrJ56nniSbp18KWjYvyL/8efLw8Fttz8P2wyvHVDDiswy3ygoFdsrewnXaZ/gn89venFlHc6f/FgdIYJbrRGySyUIuefQyicV9G1dVNX5BvzZVwxpTG5ul//KjgzdxP97QlC9cePvxN/FiOc6NYABbLrSdxRvxDQQrXsUvlHq9DsbSf/l3EL7xGcSDPhcb8GgUwriKF/GGVKcg7@KNIhhUTYN0/5/vfCcWb0wRERr7e0xraOscV9TyA/UBm/KLteJqOX/wEJzDK/SKLqaoqtYK23OuubFpI@chFB7alTlzblG7h5gRZwE2kOFj4PBjPsW1h68esY0GDLV4VasPI1RTWKksOA505xrYnkTuz2UJLrkd2mtolYIixMv1TJsnH@FqfM5wrcDRkwVlj@wfCbeL11//X3/947/@Ef1@TPd/isXDlXqpedY4aYQXExpIn1hge2qzp/yybfjDHVrRBR3AZLNZWeLxRgMf9A9sZKL3NbfApxFZCGIW5Ba4gGZQurH4e2gTxD521li4WENhkZmKwHNNhqdzJZuVDVFgE641@NEfrsiKzzVyCZwJ5Oa1xhq3XbdS31i8GW@enFSpM93/Ysvjjp/F4hKQhnT6OfCMATLf53oBtyy3A1uE1PFY/B/0asRY/BKuk7R0ddWUX6ZrteAPrFQtsuHFTZCnkytJ2njZSKeblLdmI8jkhnTSkFmb55ceLzcg3vRGc6Pu7NAtt7GOpGTeSRadhycvG82NxTiCaB4@TGNnfgjxNBInDJh4qNmrjavGVXPj6mpjA/4b9LwK3uB6tXHjT6/ZVVsBFF1XJ9jorabSaCmtoEFPwC4rDXSRlRYYGvBuA2CzGYtfIr6w5gmpu6pLTbVYOJEY9Yn1Kvp1Pcaq6rqWUwrTT4q7WiyuCYKyjl7vcGQC/qISiyOXXuHMeoUcXn34@v/Au/Xh638DVsgaflOMfB/b@Ou8wd@Tt/h74@PvuIu/52/wd/wWf899/B16@HvawV8sXmcMWKTEZtbKnmXVU/UUDCbLAoc6zA7VHg4JWYNlL7IXLDty1B6YDPhlwWRm@yw7YFk7a6sqeILBZ1kfTX14DeDXh1hc@JnZLEaePWOQioUDDemKpfe7NhNbsSYTXhnA28hqUs4m5WIyaZ4UiuM3QibZbjWTJ7W44rVaCuf6mJavkZLgqyvWbu8@e9RuK9gPWk@dg9n/4GA0b731Pzpwnh44Iwf@BwcHT6HV0w/T0kO46o30RvDajDdqm62qhMgsB2gdVzY2W42chOZiGlBUQ7f0R16zGOHdWGvFQCT@4ovz2hdf4P/8rHZeI0NkBUO7FgEEYNwAjtwBIviiViMDmuE6o1jJhsbzL1qRiRuUL87B6QsGTHr0VxZs/wB/8/9f/6cvWKp5IkI/uLzaSNEl4k8UL68ur4JnQ0ylAktqA37oAHYMcnnVQCMBXYKpmRJPxKsr7gbPlLjBI2xgGhsNCjwDBIoRj9KkdPkj9Q/7xrT51UoClwTSaypYdWu1ptmsWOuASzT/rr@jBRyxRltbEh1cdAOJTRUJopCv1dR1btbyWq2WDyylcq1WDsyJVKpy82pkN9Visarl86JYq2UDWBDOaqERojA8vVvD7l2Lj0XMLe/0qSxOAdKXAZJCVXjwIBV8S2JzPAZhXa1k372LnNrtnum22@iee/dOaAu4DaZeKYA9W373DghPUgQx/pkTLMBWQChXFW2WwlD3dN93U2/NcUbADbyeIJLu3mzWcVvJX/3wu99tJeu4DYJc8ypGgHGywsZGMd9oFPNgLpahnEKC76tJDdIVVbxKKAIvHQjdyXjgpZZLIrleJdGfxTfYZgO6pYcXu7yKU3OxfEFMdS4M8RJcQje1UuGOLF9MldOV4FdfE1ljnQW/ZrOZS@fXS@sPT05OrvH4SDprl3pdvapf6lWcEbqqdQPl8HggQ3/wIFeBOitna61Yu/1o63irjd@Vw6VuGO0YOhIRjuEy5thNNmn6rlA5aWKJTlrJZLX2kJpXLRdYPFkL4KQk0HNWrlDB454XM/t4MmtKsV671@NjppZyMIzGxrTlqJRlPVy1dZnT76@BI7QY6@ACu2dYVqhN/9xxrd652TPWYvHDJ1s7u8cZbQNGZG1vayejHb3YjqtoLczs5J1D@/PdrUcHLyDA4ZPdraPdT/c/331xCO5e7PVb3TB0Y2IY5@3J5PwNKlw32sYYXGdX2@ianv76tT6mi9U4@T0///DT73/46f/04Wc//PCz73/42Y9/9fWPvw/3H8P9Q/7@4b@tFPD5q6//2R99@MOfgeN/gvs/wv2LX339@9/hN9n/HO6/nHP78@Ceg@M3q8Yb63gBIpS1cnodxrf1SgWQgVw3YpDWb//q6x/9/Fdf/85P4P4Xwf2Tm/fv/mL5/ePvrb4x3I/@6HaYH/47uP@ExxXC/vAPuRu@b8D/IYf7nZ98@L1/z/9/FfzQ@LMPv/fn@Ags//Qnf/WXH777HzSt/Ff/@sP3f/jhez/68L3vfvjeDz587x9rH37/X6vZ@ccfffjxn/7XP/uT//pn/wv9/5ief3Kf/4ef/NO/@T//5v/@mz8L7l/A/e/B9Iu/@Q@Axn/3pz/F/4/@9O/@40/x/7//y7/70//17377X5HhD7jh//0X/5Y///a73//b7/3zv/3u1yue37/1@fU93L/@7@By/3zeJ577lOtjXb7@jfLz31Ibs1QAB0jzPdOAhd2@MFiNxbIsGzygE/74n3z4/d8C3P49gATb/ww2@HMLeP2ALF9@ueCXpnkNKf3llyAQfhkIhl/OA/2AsXcKsNvZh@8A4Evy5ReLoCDR/w2hAIwFUCHYQuIEgtslufOvvv7nP0f3KCS6/tZ8fNnQdQ42gcDvwiL@ADtzVIx52B8gOfjw0@98@Pk//vDTP/jw09/GsUDKVzJbGUm9Y9YUAAv3gEPA4n3gAFBFoRCk97WYBoa1DZzli6npV6@gEdbABNLUeqyQA1tMbZBZRTMEBFl/nSKZpnFiBO5pLF8BGxjAaUoG8EqD13YaP3Gcjk3r4Eeg@G1khsZGGWfocNqgDvFiIB4m0y6DhMKm2xQLhKynn7P2en3KA6bRoUExMMwQOj0XVE1Il@uPIMH69BHDuDDydOwVvF/VG@X6tIHRvacsQBzpbUgSoPDTy@lp4z3Y6xQnwMemj95DVsr1dLpRBpc6FZVSy7QpTbVAhaOypxmVG90Zwy2Lmw8Z@0RQywKf14CqZAE0PtMz6E2a9tsE/1Z6PSgO/UMj3esYHtppSvXD3bj/JjpT@AAA4pUk3OkGtyRhbh6C95RHlaZk4ZXmMUDNpfm0KIsciEFJx9LUvmmyQPqQh4@5NvjgjNFhcRKJBJg2GkJOaB@AYMjc06rn6y4uxhG/WGVCsSKgM@4c4tshE4ckP64/WoenCv/dNdoCTCWprccSSZyUSLIwJSmdc/JOnBciLCHZ1qkAaQJkn4AP3g8fghlqiN4zt1h8Fo6LFLTuytRinomxFH3KR6SZDwOZIBZ76g22nSlw8xlByKhFXE8R@bxI7NtOtVp/r@ZLMXiTfYIfEQo@ZwONhZ9Sljc2sNIblxJN0aARGMNirNEIFo6ZGmsc7R4D@PEBU7WszID3v8yXtHwhX9ByxWKhpKn5YiVfLJRzQMqK2YKmqZV8vlKulK6oLA@BGmSq653CRuMf3bj@h3@07Fruiles8SWbyjT/fBVrWHW@bzGBC8hCKyvUaKqIai7RzGbwp@Vy8IQ8ZtRC6WRtzbqUsMgt2ix3iUv0kM3YpTTF@e5vwMVi34ixb4AbXJAIrqGxYNfD/kEtWOHGDwHyVW5BLQDyiLEWIA@PDlrx8vJy7o7F1776ymeNBjD20v5eLA5IP2Thkq5k9uShTJ/v601cg3wHjD3a/3z/aP/gmfxo/wiY7W8zLZeVY/Grq6t@tBBBVoMdHBzEkNqA6JRTMfxVl00mE/LtgP1qqsfG81dtPI5pmqTlpJwqqTn832HQ8H9/eA3@Gj4hVE6LsRji8QOg0Q9UbiwUZ8YsGjeC89uNGC14NgGHTmL4safmSWxDiTyP8Sj9M2gLwF6bPcEtv77Djh2@tXTb6K6A2Bnyz5bvuA6IRr85zLZun3KvRyY/0xt5PdZRqac3Mv3hCogX4xEeSzPc/24x7I46kEFc@uAA2/BwLcdZBlBiLw5XlPJppIID9xaQDg4Af77/6ePjuffx7tbO41iRbR88e3TtVQiACuzJ7t5xZC1x3zBoIYri27tPnly3Bi8giTWShddYoZTJwMgCD3xn6KK3nHgZgqjyapZD93WQtJssf1KDAb5c21RxpqOQUOqqPTl8gmK65Ry6QD1bKHS/lzbM3uf1hp7oAwWubzfK79P5UjkHFWNdPpuMGrtD/KipW3ONCXsxMEDCjz3FjY4VlR/YMb3YYxCuR/jZJPxEmh/Do8A9/DQyTpV08BvFkzFb6QgvdEKjaw6GMBKcOyFArKPrDO6PvSD8vFwNlXarg8/TILcbPtYScFxdN/ssG5NpblmrlAvlSk4rZ8qVcr6gFguFjKpl1FK5VAGqnFXLarFcqKiZcr6Sy8OwAb6FSikWB2pq9hUFhkRVEOBdhWjtLmr638BPJjjysBGL8wkq9jali9C6kX3CBAPCCPjNKc@nbdzrZl3Q8njGIqcyiFFnXRbf29vJ7u0JwjZacA59JysIPbQUytlsaVsQDPLZgaFNEwSHhwEvAPO5JZvd3hGECY8A9YYIwhAtu0Xk1QXBRMvO1t4epvMaLRqGB7BT7sMtVmgpAZiNllyOmH1BeBNFB3BbPKE85XQXLZgm@uxxnx3wE4RPw/xksxDDcw7HY3gclnVrSxD2uWVrC30@o4IXeFa/iZYtugTBBQsgoSAMwDBwDcMWhA4YERUFoQum7oUObvhVBdQlYfu6IFzwCsIqEoQpQevdUwGY0sAdk3n8@LE@9HvGgF8XLn93IWvgY04nu3udTz/tDAYd92Jr99Pn6PPZZ4/11xcTtzPoBME6bbgcCAM@p6OL6xfkcb/d1q2lPt8EH/uaT/uibWDe2vobyFNwDTCRUfsz8PkMfKZLLh4bXCMA7eC1PYL3tt4hn/AiH3pPOx2hhojqX4wNnK3DPkPfTs@M9K7r1NA@ra8lU8nMRbOYPamRMxulxMts7Qp9@yn6bh/SRfHyojmtZ09AUClpwTmQlNCaagVTyKyNNoHUVdf0TVXLp6dVVArr9JMsKambKfXB@tvUM3FTy@WrQmtzUxKa6smmpparxdLL9YkgiFV8buZK1bepbDLLGD7EZulks1SYC1EqpXVFq5ZKYu0KasKHwakz8Y12O5U6N/RTUcS8IgcF@eefiL@gIpq1fmqamdZ5ptiFWJvW1Ro/zcyyN@LqoTqNCX4ci8c4gOimm9kqEu2UoFbKAqSvKClRRGqE9APer74I12ui15xhwcgvmVUl/mU9tVwUZTxW0Hb6bfq6EHs1D4msc@wLPP5DR3/DrXokZHjV2DFy2jgA6AxV9nTwY550Mh0EPa4ChvF5DLVUicUaAa95yL9rUgusnz7ekYH9DGyomEPew284O66M3x71F3y40ojQ6diY@vJjAzfgdUO3HX4oV96d4jfqTceuXUpfSFfzIY6Ap@Zp4OGEGh2oxxO@qKHE7DG93gCT3mMpSp/p4jmVs91o1Nv1kTEa@xcg4fC1XyhVGBwGTrbNOCweFwpPTLTr21AB2ZqNWroMtCam8Wms0UMdJNv17ctJtQqwVzWjTl@oFuJ4xGrTrk9sT@8bh4aLp3v2D2CwNvAYTXf4qrWLgDtQ2ZdXUsNl9qwQ@x6vo@jABmXoEjMUeLTr2avafK5TutToiLVBvYmg7/CxIQnCiSQ1352A4FSLNaD31S7iet2bdPhn3LIdkJmKtSm4qaV8bcg69c7Lac2tj4HTZzULanFOgmF6jeDfWTCQtuV2fTqrjVy9qYEMk82EUo2G@7cyWraS0VQYSWGEhZBwl8Ceh1uFG/xVlHlSVkpgTMhkp1lZzaiGmgGR8ZXZeyVmfGfXhhbJVqvYMNCoZIW3zsS0tm6leg7TNyRqY@jiNcq4nhmysQmPFIR7bugWBRBFiaWkN5vFdCErirU3kGs3kerJ2@JmvtZLbbO2CA7AG8CtsWK@1q@nXoqLdSzWUmti3TPeUH0iqaDKGK9BcwRynTcZNbNsrahmLqW2dGXpnp9QS1q1OUk0JRVKm3032BC@aggn0DRXDIQPNr8AA6xHDdxCssCZlRm7MXMbI9tpGdCKakWrBSCxcUCkUkIKP/HLt4umksmSlkyKyRrOIKyBe0DkiCIlgTwmH6ibArA7QlWoaCAuzhG3G1ngK3RFkOSuYj3TG7N8JRa/jF1dXm3M74D5Jru40NNSaH3A2CCdiDGF1r/ldpytkUmSGzTNs1XfGjzfqgXQWzuxeJW2e8325rBWcLRWUtY@dtE9vdF4yd8t3G0CqcZIK02TnQS7DLQclLk3Z4fyeZcxXqt8E4aykW4orZggUN/ma3nlgshzyt7HScE727kMP15ffYrCOEvpVd5nmyfi@2emdVnOSQ2SIlMs/j4NNYI71xrK@zgMC1dU0cH@sMvL8eUlCMlXeFxcyxVicdsJt46BbOoDGYTxpFAQcFLFYOOjysvSy/LLpy8OXhzssYfZarlanpcwWg8zGTWpJjfYQ2Bjzee7IL28Y05BfW9/Rpvm4rV4dZzM5ZO5hWD1@LSeD9dmU2qjIakbGtsEXGVVoFB9tShl3zU44jXIo6iBz4ff@kl@ulEGuwasYhXqtJDWGg11XRPj4w9f/xs8hnW5@/nWE5bEAv79X/xcK/39X/xLWiFMXtV4oUtxgESjWizFT@I8C/kSE8HCV6XVeEMJ3NWSKsY9idsge4W49y5QiJHSsmXw2zngNqEItRavxGPx8tNX7xjbADGy0RsMTI1MirIgmiWqIGzBn73Hiaj30toroCeel1Bwu2IFgcPJk/VGo7FOuxiTjTSeHNQKNGnfvKqd8MkNlEPWbfoZ3jr@jJeRw7rngT20gXV9w2CFhspAcFGUD7/1@5pW/Pu/@N2W@K79rv0toLCVSqWoavFf37zigbocDfJi2HwraxXP4EplvicfCfdrj397OzyPSN9dBg4Z1a6gTgbTwRMLpxAAeQIw4xc9gYmosnsefowFQ/ZbPI0TmDu6ZxTzoc278HAfOc774WFEr6ooA9MfTjp0@vDYvdj3D@hshgL4YoLMT@aO5XSUkY5zDfQZJw@EKIBArd8TW4FxEo9W0GcukW9FDRNt0kgEReu1AayNxUqJ1RiDlMd4Sro17fcFOl5tWL0jY6yT5hnwD8@g7vcQDPUS0eHt8NzwAk8VHRqmGjdYcodvoJfo9LdDrIyXDA8NUtUy0kxh4JEOAc8vB0eRaG@8IKMNv1wshPviAaLvoGrSEJ5/mT4KEH3reBYCy4jKUwLOoT5fIpam8qfDTODMMHegfMysQaIzB0qIcuMyM6O7A9K5ZaPWIkgrBc0qowrGplo9yXBes65SfdMxdZNt1Bkw8KiMhUqCFUqKKPumC@yaWp5T00LMGoWcL0e6HuQEAHmD4LFsVDiFJw2czmtSshRojED8k0O/4KQ@arVCI07N2IHyVXbeMX0CgKGNADCkMsAzPLyKMguo2pkM8HAE9gXZcQeK6XkTo1Aq5ylDOh62DkGBvV0A1ZRAI7RCmcOzzVEpKv6QWcaZYZH2gCDbqJ5P552S8Aw3wKC2QWTSiyKhDlTlQkmhFlKVDHd7tLv3ZOt491GGSWoBwfGEWteJYFNzlcu90@TftybeMEAjDMK7r9wp5jmSp7xM8qGSFIOsP5yv9vR8hsMI8MNNODE4TiXrFMw1RviVLB4xG@s9pFUZCmMngwP4ePKdn/IyPczKxLUQb8LKDXt@PC4gSmNacUTBhS@1QxgsWMDbgA0Izw2glbQCaiCgbm0fMBLVixDmCstOqgNhlaQG158g7Fj42bwkaquap7ZJ6js6Sx6jym4Y0om0rSWJLqCGhmE9@YmXrHWBbQ95CnaWmoiXQQlMu4@5SPGKO3a2L8L2S02C8zMCVIgIjLEYHaj55V8mgc@I4vOslC9enukue1sHDKUeJ3OivmvROcVUkmtyhWBvZeQ5gnNrdb8WBeg4vQsZFdXZvZ2hafVSb@fTGAOrafZT6XS3Xs@Jl5CkOwbi5I2BGBoozIk1dOsvuEVfmldaLRvyJ6/bxjn78umTx9Dkzw06lt58ebKeUDLA2oo1LIJeTyHQo4Onh7rrGa4oj/G9F4lNKfzQRZCIDK098prZE8p9RsCiKdgLgXIODD8ovbd9cawPnukjI5XUk/xAGCZlQqOYG7rM5aOamU6LUES9aZ4s1FFdWGxcQbwc1Alq6Br9Wgcq@rR25dXPUgOx5sNrOJ9EAZKoaxrF7kOgugePa7Vu4mevHx8/fVJPbugMY60v6RXJdCdCDkAUQhg66b7luvrFAuoAVSGs8vmZTkIYuNJJobFYlg1FbySBZV2ZnycOKaGQZTk5Q@BeapIJMM6t32zSmjvDgouxUUcHPrR9unssZCCsOzFEdLRxeLsgosXVFdTDNDi6IaWgIfDiCGHq9fyDB@TGtZTU61o2KwJq1q4gNg8wNxWJPW7tytXrvVRUkfrYXKIaQZM1Rbe9c9ReDSxvtlDadFwYIuo94CEfeEBC6qih@cz0Lx54gG31UM3CA35etL6WXy8fmNvf@rJyVHyU6nY@U4WM8NpzbBDR3PF8Blz9XOZsEdBYt8uxizKBmiy7ujLWTx0l38t2y9myWuoZpYJRzubK3YKRq3SAS@z28@VOr1LSS4VuR4HBzacg8sjEDysJHP0x2f79kl3FmJVB5O/3VeDWe4VKv6Jlc7l8p1zoZfP5flnVc7liTyt3Kp3bubZZflDcCukujh3XKfAnq5m72A3aHoQW/z8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{-x;   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1nuPLconsloPrs  \puts~-<idV=>a$f 16=B>8~+4783ngtl{Num>Ehar Cr;reu Ugele.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

This answer is based on [dfeuer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181020):

```hs
import Text.Show.Functions
instance Num(a->b)
main=print(0`id`)
```

I also replaced `import System.IO.Unsafe;` with `import GHC.IO;`, see [dfeuer's Strict answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181193).

Empty line before longest Haskell line is to fix Chip. Other empty line is for Retina. Two `>;` are for Retina and SILOS.
*Miraculously, Incident didn't break.*

[Test all GHC extensions on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVVhc5s4EP3uX7Eh/gBX5AHXdXpWIHNO0iYzbZMmnbmb87mODMIwAxIRoiXj@LfnFhK37li1RxhJ@9h97y3yklXp01PENISQDPK06vEolUAEWP7w7QQsCqoWqzQCEpXlXsiRtxdC/vnEV0xn3/iHTHPF8mofNTSgPtesyj7XUnMDYGQAfGSrLLrA@nfCdzBv/zRgpkysrpnGusRelqH3xoTIBFMPv6My9MYGzHmjuYh5fMYTVuf6ps65AXlkQP5VlnkWdeqdSSOvoWfi9akuzniUFaYSfaNH8qMUspCqTLOquOGVVlmkMyn24b5JewR/kBHLUZ7YkNJk8G2XwkzKH/0WcMY0202AwagcIcSCQ7jgzbtcMr31Z@eRQ1MNV9@4wnj0pn24WO2X/toEu@FL5MmWOb99EJo1ZhIjUy9cy0onWXNVYn1aqm3Cp6cwK0qpNFwrntcxpy/T9xeng8ur7awlP3hXiwihg1MpKv3LzjOJ7dIX3ujBBVc8ltF2DTFayXxw3kS8bP2la/I32ewiblP5/TkHblc0wyRMRBxaj7MYWBDiHYvB7vIDc76nmAMWYRgsgoIXpX4gBI67Ty/8AceWhCk8xyZKFpdC8xVXsAimgOcGFe0pwdtpvzlsemHc@jwNput6MsHYDeUBV0oq6xA1TU5EUIuKJfyaq0Sq4vKqnwC/w1clSu/@O28DT1merzckVCB@krisnjWCbfquoHVb0MvGIvA2dLdqm5Fw6dBVMGtDH9vLMbGsOSGzxzn0QtoLm8CjD4csqOqlVgyb2lv6eBTQBtfwsKIpLIPl14aqoKyRPs1RxZyLlU77FaoNjHbxjznXsBgsguanGq@DGTaS6718sR9dbGUXX3sX32QXD2W8H@M4wvkIh48D9/2j@cGBndsWgOV6jTfwXZ/7LtjeXRbfOa6W5wId8SaT1hg0tZviLwPn1fCP3I4lsGPSeTzz57QrnLkplBlebMTdcJZ3AMchYJP7k/GrN57j0HusWvXteDB1TkY0tqewcHAhAQ/HEMYjmgT2V@dXjR1qHzhBxe87PQuWiU6M8gDtCEo0Rveruph5cDD23TVZkE3OKt1v/zpmdX9GfGTrPa6OrX9Da47WbKD3Pw).

Answer (score 4):

## 252. [Ahead](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ahead), 11600 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEQCIMA3KVKvlk7rTHdL01KfPnNINRskQRItEGADoES1Wl0zk9RcT@zKdSZzXePxjc/MJE7sJFXxTd1cTyp2ucrzNeXKJ/@Adr6kXCnPP5istTbAl0hJPXGqAhLAfqz9XnvttfZjoaV7/V/9KooXO3Ksy57l@Mw3PJ91XPPccGW2c8m2dNPLaZlIBKG23d5oYNi@V45EmcqYbVywA7ttdsCN@c6ZYZtvDRf8NMaGrtNz9QHz@7oPFhNCsYeG9W7wzmdtZzDQ7Y4HkBnGjnTw7I7aZ0xveb6rt33TscEry9hz29IHrY7OAMJwh67hU/Q5BlG0zyjMvE@esSeO6xmYfNvwPAcdC4xtGIOhf1kDSxEgdNd0Hm8//WwhcImxz3TI2dAyxgt5UdPshWm4nYUQqsq@ONnfX3TV2Dckx2b7N/OnZthz19MtfTH@LNse@c6Bv@ieY9s9w9aZJpdkbdEzz3Zc/UaQAnMNvdM1LUM27TaTWN@whobL0IV1HReazDesYrqYbm5PQ8ptDFucei5EWw0vprs9DzydcwOMBrTE0DQ6rOs6A6bb3gWkpJbSU3iMtjSPDm3IICAae@1B6I7BPNscDg2fe0JxDZe8IWVmmfZZhGPfket0Rm3T7gGcAfU6HPlUJi/ShmA1NgxwWEYDi1ItcDDIwrEzMGbbwgPkhVx7Q6Ntds02rxxj7Bu2B@X1ZGZC212YlsU6hgUBprG3U8xz2MibcWpZel9uyxGsXEyFDc4sZrL2cMi4FxQDsrSfLjJj4Lw22Vvwt/oeGw8HzDMH4O23nW7XMNhbY9iH4GzQiXScCIOrPVwo2cQWMwDGNqB0u0ffgnrzsTrtLmStw1ozcJAPyjOVWLcdqD6X2fqAY0N7eEmlh2gmIbqOI6N7xzE8O@6zC8c9Yy2jrWOxMTHP6HX1kQUpml1sDsAD02MDB97QiDaDbEFgH@sC48bEIksLgsmEzWsMoWNi8zqILtDWYStfuDrgh@sF7eibA8AO0497zNA9EykWBPEMu0OYMZzQMgdKO9vo7NyEjgdVMXIpbs9wCfUpXoalgCj1Ca4mLlzTB4zAUmyzI0N32YlrGCLHU8Nr60PE0tkkITEHU/CxIDIh5sZGfO9wPw4IykPI@hAQ0s2cfPPziM7kKos1K3BXBaES2Xv6kF3FGmjmNBOQeOgmdJFV3zNPaTQMuMdqS@m51xGINQK1YjHFGfqKLg0hg5IPGVR0NKJJOtfkoTWTMNtYaIOZbsOhOtAaQATYFykqWXvkukjdp5Wqn0GhLcfuQX1CYd2RzZs8n4YmAPzreClmnBuIA7yNnAuq4ZM@YAj8AXSGsvABhyoUhhzoikGNhul6jjUiOAjp@dgfoVYgKMZ40GVfsK5uWhgE/DEqnmvX8AA5MczI7mDLD0zb6MgszAZRHRf64jkkp0Ok5AC9YTBDWyhTAAwN4VBR0evDb/9ep9eDeLbbbcftBOj6BSB7m4ZGnTILgxtDhHVs3aJsAVwKU@fBIYFz3TI7ROV0@zJIgjJBqV44I6vDqKNemNDl@joQWwMIRNs3OJI7Ix/ymGID/YxTRJNjLhR8oLegYSkBSpuKLbGtXWilNnRzwhlpMPK7RSYN91jcU14mNsuJzbWGAZkTZXE9pii9CiCcvE5OYIvfhjlfbM8NFZ6ve47ZiQwv/b5ja0xqM6FddYaGnYjPxRFPxd1WXJSRUifEillty13T7iTiG4CLNUg4Llba1XbdLJ9WFoLPJgnRXGA02F2NRFsUkNRQpzhXBsBcyEDJvpAC04yf4zWxytFbnnHGill0O@cOUWJdEC8dRBCgQ7JnGcYwkZZVEckEwi0tN3osK@lCHEGBy@ZpMh6NJ2eLTjFASecKip31xHSQbFnDPvIbUCm2NwSa6yLutnXAHg8HNR9YuhRrEV7TSAiUhWjihREHqt0CQhriEXVJ3uUwvISEMohh2oXme7LRmenIQASgL/veDWpsOcgdUJ5w5AHSYWOieg@aBgLzgmzzgvCUyGW@SGc2EBSMrWWwotQyoRNgdwOaHuD8TNkAPKNxGIiNd5IZ2jPQL3FU46zBtMPgmKazAZAH95K1DaQ5QHwMPqBgIiPqfx7wvczpsrSk5XLzfexGF/NdZVv6Coj0W@XWnoSFn@1MSGhYF9hsS7d7I70H9MKxIYjebhtDPyBUUBLPB1K0ON6QoxQMnrLXj8S2FtOmQSRkj6ZpIJHnrRcMhTpSl4Btl4AnQ9aPywKsY7pAlmAkX0gdAM4XEhdeIchcBl4JK7IQcgCAZMbYaI98oGqAwBd9s90HnMXc2Zwu8kFoMXlwmk0dKLvUnSSNmVFrD7SIrEycMBsro5CwRW/GA4MrRlWbc6DGn3W4PWbdGyyJ2JlkEQaCGVdZ0WXAvTviHDi2syRSqMhJtAgy78PbATixY2SKYeAK2S7qrBNOedJE0GZANaDnA/71fX/olWGcMP3@qCUDpign7uWBf2gjsii@e2n6Dje3LKcFZNmD/qmEKSjtUcscLxSI3CZt@NqLnAMD1vVYFUbuNyPAukS86wHBJPddBJ7xEohwUxT8KQAgAclQUYmuR6R4H4jK8aXdTghzSCmkmIB9VxDBgAEnVfM5Mm/z2XwNTou5RLDZzMgKQime2yaDNMOTYvQITtmKfDJXtHvmMfKJIMCjq1ueAW97ZFloHdmcyiU4ryCyq8gnnwBpS1By5mBomW3Tb3Jf9uBBwFOwNZDxkG3qIs8kQphPAmFaBoICMMHww6Fl3zkmZjchQkE@uZ5L2HBdx@Xp@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@xFjTK312eH@3rMqJdPXvTPgKaQewirAK0OtuB0ZqIE16hiRZTBANsDUnuYE5w4w8V67zSSHEZjU5pmYGS7abEVsQGuI8XSYZA3mi@D1Ib@7c2WgSMidQt7Gv7TDLHHwpXmaJLkPFHv3@PHcFNngDPgJ1vYsZL4llxcArMo6d@zQayJjlNkByWg2MJiAW8BfdiZzAbZjS0gLQ3HOmU2IT4gABLkht4WchDkHgxF3zTGIxFGcTwlYf@RYkfvfdWwQTg35BVFDgQEhx9kqQ17K/x9xRkpue9PeCZw@GIeW3gZ6Px9dQ2ANiBAokKIs9xErNyJeFA5Ijr@rjMBKtXUb669jkpw6Mr0@Vi/IEjgKuF2oVRRScXKHau2AtYHL7UFNG2PT51Ir9PBjDPJI9xIiyknbXM5ALEMeGTMVztwRA@u0QcI3gFdGXz5dwvbsc9N1bKxkeQ@iBlJUwTZYiHxZ9QIabW8faA9X1@@yyKHGbjirM3U7G@ti5bY96F22Yzk9h60DAKKmLHPEPrBxhhOkHF8fQo8y31IFbfccEPXncdAwJnOm@cxE3tQRUiF4@TWMAmx5oacAK8p8fPDVHrAhai6dhvyHtjRdk0LOxLJYRnRssylAsApgId5gS35lDPuX7hw6eU4wb@LT5CF1TD6TpQMLCbkKevhbCjrbybkL9PPQqxOalpV9j2QCnLyblavnSj/HrfBuAyWMLjija1gVc5HeaPBp@yLhaihzdGsyVSB1B46vK1/IQKLxEUEOWTKZ4CnxtbgiSfgUyItpNaZ0jHMFqdQ05vGe0V4a99gw2gr64uDGQsPS6gk9V1RNAy6bHlBM/g7rYBJysfy9ZBIJO@VukjbPNAzyJ/2RETHafYcJDRAxZksmwADRB1lZgpoHBhDlkkmwYEUo4jsjEOs6hmUOTP@A5uwtG2UXmYi3jFQr8N0FejON4Mg0gCHnEw7TQQbn1adjlN3j8M@AklOsIOLLvEpdo6OsT2N74jguyJUeU2lOQZtU/SDwUBxv2JH9MUTAQ@3R@O6F4/zTw4d7zaPtk0dVZeS5imW2gEZ0jOYAhFkLusOKC/OGM4R7gDum7QxMKFEY5dsz65nj@Jx5wIWD@11RDBjG8fhh8/HBzrPtZ98KMkcjujkYWTrmsRxbAJjEcUwwt0bTdloO8Bb2aGVMwFwc7hw@DmP5/Pnjg@3mw72jw5OZaF6PLFNXx8rwrLeqQJ8jCFPlNK/6Q6szv6JDYurcLEJAbFDmqjCQTZkkwVNCN54oSmUyeiCLjMOjJOEssI7z3C7T1HSp1GnpxaKR77Sz2UJX73Y6WU0t5rrFnJZLw6OQLxnsHYFLkjGmmRsw8VkRnEDCNCDz9FLlbMjhgCjaBo7lcmm@Jr63ZK6dyxmFbEkvtUulkq4VOhldKxYMI1/oZtNpI6@mu62iWszcmrmZbCBrNbUNaAYIeh1OFpAnEL8EvOa6A8888HoXrKNpWr6d65YyWieXznZapXSu2GmpBb1VMtLdbEbV1E5bU8thWJxRBSrRhwZDrtIG1jT0klTwFCPhYDrbxLTKGC5DBwQnlkESMwyXkVFwCDyy6DEKFpFxajZwz6F7uISMUzSBex7dB7iAPOVkyTpxDACLBIjryLLbCh1L6DhZQZ5bWwVSGdDPZf6rAwUxX6npa4z8AtegZ8p3parkfu53u3POGjmfSTiUWVPnDDnzFej5td@gsDe8lgJP4stSfHzleml8N7yWAk/iy/H4cMV7eXQLPstAJ5HlKTJcIV8a14LHEsBJTAWKaXZVfepXJL9VS@pBWku9VwaaxF2iuPlqefM1X61oBovliM28g5wAJ/bYAf75sYnz9t25HhOZSOCNiBBOI8xPJE19tOkyCZPOl6/vCLMRcWJg2mcOCc4TUzMtqzmMZRLF4My6GbILogY95kBvZOqmDx@/Bq0uPZYA4KC7ODNHHjTtGQz9MNTqyjN64QToshzMT@XOJd8yuiOQgpSWaaP5DjCpVCTIbqtlrgKFmsDNB@F7CViZPRuBJKrJWVkNxV5cOgGazedhTw4OCbClkxA3P//P5irfH7k@hAre//nbHWiEm03U1y9JFpwYmrZxQfjRXdliQVC00GN5605HfaoYMt0VZVvHJVfdmhiWR02tL0l93R2gyBU0NyAoPgATbsE1nnM@FxO@lydSZlTJ8@sMzDYHrL0EmmAXlkR4YiRkW47eoWrgorBpUCAXG5s3gzHmQuEMwwMjz6qElqxcsOlWAb8/8kf8ibsD7mpGc4j3bV00gEzn9JZqAIust0zjlkZ39bNRx5GA06MiY8byS2CnpafJOqlr6Wfc2ETj8uLzArpmrwf8RPBeBXbRB9mGhFLlgl534YVnj7yh1ILG8qHjkI26wuCWFFyLP1eBmMH@uYlhda2ZFj3u0egT5CJ0AZaOKhq3NEkzlWYuVLOlty5RVO9/PJZhgsTgAM2ptpPJdAaHvcna7@xWpNXhcayk8KXS8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyB7olaZ0Z40qKHk4dT01LQGneRmpbugeo5QfNYZxD89HjNnTHkakNYpc7Nd2C7NPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVtxzI97NrWKgq6uAA3TRO3s9FjZkraXFaxHeKZvL40MS2nC07bx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoGc2RnVaW1nQu8V7IWfefc4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs710ROm078JU3A5Ej@X1eLY0X37bWuo@3wfCKY5ZAe2eeO2ZluOxY3reVi09F4Lx53KMnq1BU7clWg@aNS8PFmRqyORglnVFu@pWz7HyxZ6iw2Nl44/cLo4Jwfu@1G9CvVT1buoV8keOrQbvlWT/THHP7mo7WppwcdF@xnjLCLyMhAWLkqsLCJIE7sRZXrj9dJFCygqXl1c1gNvuX@iX4fvXGFlW1W44sgwvid8G9g8DlIpg8F3Og/86qWVvT61zP/J0I9rCXYWYadwzy4CBjJ43mpRpafUjQ6jp9P2JVdcaGSNjKa06bL02cH/7LVLI/TOVDooRC2Y7cUYI5zonUG8D@fFeucYxHG23EhjdMqGT38npLKV3Q@DRhyhyH4HhCA03A/bs0XCuceekOPvZ7TXXH4Y92@nMZRJ9PpYiFe/mp@YYec@g@1bhiguDuLZVzaTT6YC/mZm/nrPcJnRlJmFfm/w5lzC5TFOewuJsiDtjXJ7GdCoVmt488ySc1LwfddJWzQgQcKmk2KZt@Jf4XNUky6hty3Gsj2lCILodE/k34Epx4eeuprzBGwW7wdh07sPDmZNWd9WsBx@QAukUag8F79uwYXbq9V7NLOGSNfTS3oL19nmgmYncu1KBYZ4ml/jWCWs14xnMqKhyUS7c2iM5O@u0DEvnr3E@e1t8JTlza3wTliXgk2ltC9fD@ArYdEU1ukC3hpdQWWYHhJy@MTDIeot0oHdej7zwtRJo7OC9xFum9cZV4YYmEAobn3OrbTOslO/YIJb5utszUK6xcFU8cF1FnMNZ9aWVezDQewY/V3Ub9ZxOdeDWYS4NTo3LJz3KfNdZG4LxrR@3owJ0pjPj0gvfSyN8ctmG9hwN7p6qW@j3bdqodFdHl5Wliwl38Ip23@nbfaPPdwJNbKu6B2Ckz0/E3VYIyH@v32ZEn2Z3Kc3WrOVY1n1qFukjp5aO012apz08p9WBoB8V76XeAo/gdecUIIz1VEE06K/qN31jBEOW5/jO0JDItgrUwski/lxFRcPFnV93FurWGQKokfD968Z/p2za0x1/OKRXc2iNPHpQUImO1y1ryn1K5j5YYfp82xHHW6PntNp9864stQzdt80zJZwR4tZbJdvhTC2YTHqIzrJlQuW5lzJiQ3XW/xhfB6uaNJhc4sPWxLC8jctsd@S6l1gTvuMwz3IupvRhfv/EZBqXrz6gYVUOgpXBJd7EDeDOunAH2S1LIMFC4koEIyYcGW7JSAPDoq6cUZrb3jnTOzIZ/ljFFy2UnzI1s377MVOiwbYHmhw0Z2ZuwX0Of@YWo5cOVnZ/1PNukjs@Yd8BFgsfS1t6u4dnmhcamjcqjEC6HbxW1bdmKbh9G95NaLmRcevqSu7W5RWCUy1Jd0x4NeEFbThaOW1mmUOPP5nU1ZYyDDeXkG9CXS4Xm4P26RhdvhaCprs4vYHj4iEiYCmktmt4bZxKR4rM@SdOfWynB5RZstgUOIRdWoSbq9ZLm38y4klfPjV6Om6vfGziTktrCVZArIuL13dF@s2R7pnfHDm@sTS@xQXsu6J7ovfM9qO5mg8jC2s02IPHX3Noj043K/@ib3p0fiM03DLnhEjG0RbxrAn8/jJpbWG6fnIw@vZplRlGKdj7zaQDFu4RnxhwwQD99aVpLZuJd4YkN16S6bZJeNOnmdngvRSrlm8CuC35i9FgOPKC1/LUaZ/O7BT14IzcvQsTyKL0Bqgx6@uWv3wae2ZmFniuYJCcGldx4V@ZltNjXxXTDFg0GLSRKV@CcDswXB/pPvQIewkCU9r3XCjFSQ/J5QV7AzhhZJhk2qZ/@wSP7@sgI4VvLAwfbPAUovIYn/LWx8YgnSyvkce3cjAwtl@2LTwU/7GSACe7gIXHdGgdjZNz87N4HyRj7AYRhqOLbVzMymu3LvqUcUh17JEv4S7/28aU/K1jSpmNi/kZ1GCJb@49eS7OYghtf72LDzVAEBx51uXUtHLjwQLimTYwa6tp8Tx0KE08NEilwTPaqHlHmO0hnp4ikv/QWSbxHF3C6HNvkQkGkNHgodHGlcc7037qPAHWDYayIRDdwTMDtwws0JLlATHYY6etW1A/nTuTOaZol4wVU@FaHxotaF9ralrOiy2L@KHu6yt4J5o4JAlwYroTV0yrZbivaUZwxrxKqJ3P0CNjTGLIaoThvVDy223OcOO03FwfWVzb8YaOY/MnEeE0vNQntxMbGB7ocf8Vdxn3L8@NfkuFtPnSHp7z7SZGhx/cW1Vc12g5Fn9iEVaQA9vkmwt01zQ85bFpj8bkxiTg3ZaLOXwbb1ou4DSH14fOdmGCjD3Z3Yub1fhWYW9BkgKW@Fz3aMl/uUwzt5P4/ruK@rrbdnDtLDB85MrZzJGwO@j4ZKs035rQgkYZA0HT26NQr8AdWbUGrQE9VsokMy39zGjhkbsWnR/19fEyJnL@6FjguHB4KyRp2PHzLHEEUo9490C2KLLN17g5pAcR9IulaBIm99Q02m918Q5aOulFNJes6CTRLu1I85vggM2xDMnv4x5LxfdXEYyn5tmoc4@1rnABZTQwcM16fuVmJVI5Xp8wwlm@Sj8huK4RbN3GXYLQ9UMzUl1peyXKYvTwP9z5XIGBuZnP4gn@0VjqATm7e18AZH7k2sHrPmh35Hh@1xwfDlGNk@Ouoi9YrBwEgRfvDmhaX1UIaE97ZPH5jt7Mjq5Bh@Q74Aa7DpgsIuG@IRn2uUQqjsbhcqWrh3pkVrbh4uZQ9Y7doRfeZD0QPKShR29l6B0dPD48kYeeesvMIW74G5kWru5RVkI3KCCZbgYNTrGQwp2JagYvFZyvAjfTDc5we3KoPSo4jEa0JTwWAY56uz3CaRBoH5kRYCKhJ5OiGAlCPXIu2ABV02Agj85UnpnDCkuHRqzFPgwfBI@nyhMsprONKtPSaSaKFa6gAdhJqMCRUWFdM4x62/PMng1ZCHNAunVQ7wZX2@Mx4FH9MN56ncWuxuV0Wb1mVSaUBXZ6ynOMFyWyNx6SYpxnPHg9pp9WY3FJisfiDbvM0vEJuGGBbLYUXJ@DhcziK8jwpH650iyHNF5NarPC9YoAzUSdPX3d7lgGe27TmiSU3@XaMbjqlRPca/uLP@wEqoxIZdfA9HQLKgS1kTkDo@9cbPJ0w@oaDnVUhYRxgJhtccUc0u42AxnPb/e5BiNoruf7J8VAL0qg@gwsR3ymbJILjjm4XIdnPH2OGDw3k/N6QcKTUGGhQHgYDWwYrTt@35PZsUnHN0fu9EBGoBDO9l2ck@@k2AHrGLitkU7l0hKU5ThndFIHc/KLP@TaYOhsbnBmMkyetEDNpIhHcFVSwdJuOyPIdRjJW8N1ApAEVjII1iNc8CUlZOQu4olVUlMD2C6FSlooGa6pZXf7mEl7LI7qzVCpQsXsJmLbzz77op4@rb5nA8X4z99WxKug4oRPpVLeE1IsBKlcI2LNeufAe@obZ0JsLPAEJweXzUA8uODtgarZOJLh2eUQxxxnGHYb5DdJr9QEGwN9DQk0UzuH2loGpKOLENa4IG0tdELORgJIOuI86GBgFSlq3uuqscSIr0FKxz7LQYKo8UYHE9fqRUd5UfMIBomN2TtGRAoYTjWXBhuvSAuV3QyqO@Gm98zsYQTlodEa0Ybcc03WclUqTqxZ3aiRCQY0B5VO1V82xlpaaowLe6fAQgeV2miMP01rX0KtOy6EeqBgz9t7@vAqJtfS7955@iUThOt4hR@eADIRuzo6ONo7Ptk@eX4MrXAdkrZ9foQqpDWIRXQqsu9YpM4L6gV52Y@gPxPblAyiwkhRjMyeXyPQoK4FSYhx4wxpmgt9R/Bl4T1jxv8mQEDTuiaLTEYGwAKdkA1rDQs/GqJSMhaEDRQrEZaZOH5gB5pUDB5RWUJLqaoEVoXKkqCy7llVbHVhN7nbfWrszlhur7bNpSBYY5P06hN/XsSlVXD9d1Luoe55//Pl5rHcXm6CuaXcADpxDcPsbx88fv5sbz5YOMgT1a2WcsHBTU6csadxfjjUJEX6EoKAuIZbFZhAAbg1GMy4PkvDvzCgWAFxbA94YMJQyr8QmSIm1EwVVaqeBlxIIkE5QP4GGZHFc6XArM5kMRyjZ6K74kWcEIF9YRJ1mHFZCGKOkmpQGa@wGBhrUF1h1zsiIh7Q67g3y/6kwh6HRcMxeuTxPrdiqJqMOh6D/8yoFJq0UzZmwXCmnjKJaXBbht2DAoewYoWPUSzGK0KI8bwLk/yiSkfIU@e1TssmdF4iOI8Jo7SlD72QGYyyp45vlNmbkUM6H0JiMuEvSJuozjWwUtNyvaKkSwLkVOCHw3GL4jvYP64id8ZZM6Lvszg3snGgAiCuDDU4le27qDSYH5flWgl5lTuBArxwqKSpBy9QeDXhEjx2bnomCM7UCF3kcSyglFiaoOCoUJe0fbBtywOepAPDN3AoPg61wJzIdIiPn@STbCZEASflCcuYYkIEYb3qTYVoMJReoCj1igeOERzF7M3EGd9YkySouZ5ph9pzy6hOl6TuMvPdEe7Rq8VvBAmzUCaT1PcH1gzgEtWQDUP58Nu/x9VBNnwwfz8wj9M7YPvNwNYF82@FPqoKtn8ysWlg@wG3vVSwyW7qwJvmc6LOYOWxR0DOLeFGwZAwhHqEqUCTJsfm/uLgiHltVE@LDTrQxzNthWQmlFOYOQDMOKeGRnCewrQdp/Ek6l8AngByAZIgj4NsDaVnuKcJVIdWVhTMOK6myLRZ0hjzDQykHe3NCLWCAiem5HP5rKpAJqXzMEJS2NLDs1s8QlEsA2GMnJvD6qtWm21sbDDBa@uWUc1XOIIoMf1lRng1yWgMYCNcWqgzCANBpiHArxYES8T0pCpiUBzN4mocCVvH4fgGLGGCDAAiorMdqngAntMJqgqQ2TbGPrFNl6EUBFTbdmbUAYcRSRARjxt1Vy72yel5LJwCnOml8mwzCC8Q7BjBysIyjK2/ZA2/YZ8GOkwZYN9PluCvDeZ/tESxKccsVGFzU6NmYlEfJpaGbR3bDs6k7kNuWUJTtIyi5sUZDBWCqCC/2N/fQZTQw4FitA3ztTP0tnf3Dj4/PDq@oVmJIOOLYHEWr20kG5Kcqp9ODPFJvucrdWdfOX6ysx9W5WyupnOZCDHdnLqYzWWpLeZ0Reov@NG3m2mTx42E1PR9I6adX9I@bfK@GfvUV5kB3OUnb26kmhCvruunG7WGHb2R/Ltl2nKj8joiF5gaHunKjS9mE7M40Yx/gprxPTk8163ioW487ec7Z9Mj4oHDjAcHD2MBChCRlRBqFfGEDBzyGaCpLhONq@b3iPTxWSLSYTrJ0QzkSajEH7vWVPVeoHOur3t9y2xFYADvoB5GrjEmVIky0TUje0PL9BNihKZAqsgGARFLBKr8x@WxTEuwCdKYS3Gl2G1q7ML4xAh0AogvfjTy@uzIGc7MbT00QtMz4EbYwxFfnzPY56MBwHXp9cxAEmsAfyJBYKio@CSrXKqGnhVosRsnUVMgpFdHXXZBweVBJ5cYi3LfGHfMHhDwhJiCnv6pCmzV5Jw9Fpo029lxoHG8hj/DE0@zVfpRygzH08j1ui6bdscYJ1A7T/kU@FN0j1@8OI@Lwg0cII2Ku6EOtgXVimFH1P2gR0zVEi50ttJEf/@C7stSCTUcocoAaBZI8dh3H4MRxqdEd6APWWJEOj89JjOyJhoJO@X5rsikGlcbYrNkkqRqeJEHcM0I2iUTIQ5L4DxkQqlC66CrZ3fw9dYcsroqy6dgpkREFsMZtV0YynEuSoyAlARByhRtFduWlTFHHHtljnkQBv0jpISMoeLLJd6kqpJmuB2sCyo1qz2YUd407YG8VkulctAa86SmxAAtblJ5WYFol5CQkEuF@g1OgEOtoSp31PmPCwBAFra@Ydi2ARUEODPQYQzWR4BkrpgKv92Rmqr@phSiPIuPgiPlkNF5leB78SsLV4ljSoUmZyrXMKa@auCg2g2G1Uvl7yuyUrlKxKzqpQKMjlhLxPpVNZlZTyZj9noiZuNQ/@ABzulcx4CTaMogIo0BSIpZYgXwGTiPasyuxPSNRKxT1dYpBFhBSLuCAO89Rb6K6ddK7AGM1ClwcXnnTcQ80iqZlmX1GvKHPSSmpABnrlAJH324A5OPmckk5kGONTED75XGcZJoduNYoemjSsCNKr1B0N0WqOqkJW58toRXYOAcNDQQdg0Je7CTvxkCTxWCZ5b5reA9eMLfwMNSjPZnGt4s@y/M@9yfsAT0Lk4Kv7gOT67WEypwnIBKRGtKF0UgJr/6VVTNMyER28xnzpPxXLoCD7VSYDn2aayhZaMsugXiurIuuMJV42HxnBldLf9Gkup6V35zenR2dPSl2EjEo7uHLwU1C6AFVqL7vleBaSsu9nFXNLquRKLKuvqgoCivXr0Cdheuek2uzULJp2Jdip/WEwWw1AqF9VS@uJ56thVvYlbEhKaJx8w0FdYwh16nA7fTp8/nJKL8YpubmBYY4M8Ct8G4y92mmeEggWsYNvS6A67c1HNR1ijo@noyq23ZFVlLa7/4@dp16uqoufGL7wwUYw1fh/j6/vUTNB@ruU/X1j7d2clmU1B53Hz01dG3tre3sw9TuaN6bjMrpdc2/uLP1tY0bUNT1k49Tz2N18@@FLR0VpB/8bP40dE3m56H7YdXhqlgxGcRbpXlcuyMvYXrrMvwT@a3nRmzjuZW9y0OkMAsV4nYxOO5TPz4ZRyL@zaqqmr0kn5NqoY1ptY2C//lh4dvon60pikvXHj70TfRfDHKjWAAWya0nUdr0Q0Ey19HL5VqtQrGwn/5dxC@9jnEgz6XG/Co5cK48pfRmlSlIO@itTwYVE2DdP/bt78didbGiAi1g32m1bR1jitq8YH6gI35xRpRtZg93ALn8IIAWk4Dp3EIo6iq1gjbc6a5sWknzn0oPLQrc2bcJu0eYkaUBdhAho@Bwy8t5de2Xj1UlBoMtXiVy1vNENUUVigKjgPduQK2xxMUfCZLklSR5BCwIuEVFCFarKaaPPkJrkZnDAsFnjxZUPaJ/SPh9vD6y//vL3/0lz@k34/o/k@RaLiHQqqf105r4cWEGtInFtie2OwJv2wb/nCHVnRBBzDZbFqWaLRWwwf9AxuZ6L3gFvjUJhaCmAa5BS6gGZRuJPpeUVgZq/28NnexmsImZioCzzUZnsyUbFo2RIFNuNbgR3@4JlZ8rpFL4EwgN681VrvtupX6RqL1aP30dLzBbo9kMc7lcUfPI1EJSEMy@Qx4xgCZ73M9h1uWm4FtgtPRSPTv9KpFWPQKrtOkdH1dl18mK5XgD6xUZWLDi5sgT6fXkrTxspZM1ilv9VqQyQ3ptCazJs8vPV5uQLzJjfpG1dmlW25iHUnxrBPPO1unL2v1jfk4gmi2tpLYmbcgnlrslAETDzV7vXFdu65vXF9vbMB/g57XwRtcrzdu/Ok1vSorgCbX9Sk2eqOu1BpKI2jQU7DLSg1dZKUBhhq8Aa5ej0SvEF1Y/ZT0kFWluprPnUqMusQ60CmlrK5rGSU3/jS/p0GP9xBcEwRlHQ3vcGQC/qIUiSKXXuLMeokcXn34@l/j3fjw9b8BK2QNP/hGvq03@Hv8Fn9vfPydtPH37A3@Tt7i75mPvyMPf09a@ItEq4wBcxTbTFvp87R6pp6BwWRp4E376b7awcEgbbD0ZfqSpQeO2gGTAb80mMx0l6V7LG2nbVUFTzD4LO2jqQuvHvy6EIsLPzOdxsjT5wxSsXCIIf299H7XZGIjUmfxVwZwNbIqp@W82TzN5Ydv6vHTSlRpNBTO5jEtWyF9zdfXrNnce/qw2VQQ8RtPnMPp//BwMGu99T84dJ4cOgMH/oeHh08aQLBqya2ktAVXtZbcCF6b0Vpls1GWEH/lAJOjysZmo5aR0JxPAlZq6Jb8yGsaI7xra40ISMEvXlxUXrzA/8V55aJChomVG5oBQADGDRCKO0AEL6Bnvmi8UF6QDa5zipdsaLwAz9DEDcqLC3B6wYAzn/yhOmatfwd/83@v/5PnLFE/FaEPXF1vJOgS8SeKV9dX18GzJiYSgSWxAT90ADsGubquoZGArsBUT4in4vU1d4NnQtzgEdYwjY0aBZ4CAqGITtKkdPkj8Xf7xrT51YgDbwQyayJYcGs0xum0WGmBy2TWXX9HazdihXa1xFq43gZymioSRC5bqajr3KxltUolG1gKxUqlGJhjiUTp5lVLb6r5fFnLZkWxUkkHsCCSVUIjRGF4eruCfbwSFTGzvOMn0jjvRx9qiAtl4cGDRPBpj83hECR0tZR@927i1Gx2TLfZRPfMu3dCU8ANMNVSDuzp4rt3QHPiIsjuTx2@9JqQVPapVqMUSiCUa9kCeDNV0aZp9nVP93038dYcpgTcnucJIilXTqcdtxH/5Q@@851GvIpbIsg1q2IEmArLbWzks7VaPgvmfBEKLsT4HptEL1lSxeuYIvDiguwdjwZearEgkut1HP1ZdINt1qCjenixq@sotR/L5sRE69IQr8AldFNLJe7IsvlEMVkKftU1kdXWWfCr1@uZZHa9sL51CizN/IUEtXKlV@OKEr@uXullnBu6rrQDBf54aEZ/8CBTgoospiuNSLP5cPtku4nf/sOVbxj4GDoSdY7gqubQjddpIi9XOq1joU4VpRGPlytb1OhqMcei8UoAKcWB1LNiiUof9byI2cXzc2OKd@Fejw6ZWsjAmApDamRI25AKadbBlVyXOd3uGjhCy7EWLrp7hmWFnz24cFyrc2F2jLVI9Ojx9u7eSUrbgBFa29/eTWnHz3eiKlpzUzt5Z9D@bG/74eFzCHD0eG/7eO@zgy/2nh@Buxd5/VY3DN0YGcZFczS6eIOa8Y2mMQTX6dU02qanv36tD@liFU6YLy4@/OR7H37yDz/89Acffvq9Dz/90S@//tH34P5DuH/A3z/4t6UcPn/59T/5gw@//1Nw/E9w/0e4f/7Lr3/32/wm@5/C/eczbn8a3DNw/GbR2jpegA9FrZhcT25BTW4l10slwAvy2YhAcr/5y69/@LNffv1bP4b7nwX3j2/ev/3z5fePvrv6xnA//IPbYX7w7@D@Ix5XCPuD3@du@L4B//sc7rd@/OF3/j3//0XwQ@NPP/zOn@IjsPzjH//Fn3/4zn/QtOJf/MsP3/vBh@/@8MN3v/Phu9//8N1/oH343X@ppmcff/DhR3/8X//kj/7rn/xf9P9Dev7Rff4ffvyP/@r//av//6/@JLh/Dve/B9PP/@o/ADL/zR//BP8//OO/@Y8/wf@/@ud/88f/99/85r8gw@9xw3//Z/@WP//6O9/76@/@07/@ztcrnt@79fn1Pdy//l/gcv983iee@5TrY12@/rXy8z9TG9NUAAfoKwVMAx5359JgFRZJs3TwgE74o3/04Xd/A3D7dwASbP8n2ODPLeD1fbJ8@eWcX5JmOqTkl1@CiPhlICp@OQv0fcbeKcCGp7feAcCX5MsvNoGCRP8fhAIwFkCFYHOJEwjuouTOv/z6n/4M3Sch0fU3ZuNLh64zsDEEfhcW8fvYmSfFmIX9PpKDDz/59oef/YMPP/m9Dz/5TRwRpGwptZ2C4fz2eVQAzN0DDgHz94EDQBXFRJDn1yIaGNY2cN4voiZfvYJGWAMTSFnrkVwGbBG1RmYVzRAQpP91imScxIk6uMeRbAlsYACnMRnAKwleO0n8InUyMq6CH4Hip6wZGmtFnKvDiYQqxIuBeJhUswgCDBvvUCwQspp8xprr1TEPmESHGsXAMEPo9ExQNSFZrD6EBKvjhwzjwsiTkVfwflWtFavjGkb3nrIAcSR3IEmAwi9lJ8e192CvUpwAHxk/fA9ZKVaTyVoRXKpUVEot1aQ01RwVjsqeZFRudGcMdzJubjH2qaAWBT7TAVXJAmh8JqfQCAjg4N9IrgfFoX9opHsdw0M7jal@uBv330RnCh8AQLyShBvg4JYkzM0WeI95VElKFl5JHgPUXJJPlLKJA7EpyUiS2jdJFkgf8vAx1wYfoDE6LE4sFgPTRk3ICM1DkBtBQHPPyp6vu7hAR8xjmQn5koDOuJsIN5vFjki8XH@4Dk8V/ntrtDOYSlJZj8TiOE8RZ2FKUjLjZJ0oL0RYQrKtUwGSBMg@BR@8t7bADDVE76lbJDoNx8UNWollaj7LxEiCPrskYiW1DeSDWOSJ19txxsDqpwQhpeZxhUUMZkdOyhp2mMheOQ3PbznlcvW9mi1E4E32EX7@KfgQETQdfgRb3tjAJqhdSTSFg0ZgFvORWi1YWGZqpHa8dwLgJ4dM1dIyAzHhKlvQsrlsTsvk87mCpmbzpWw@V8wAYcunc5qmlrLZUrFUuKaSbQFtSJXXW7mN2t@7cf0ff2/ZtdwVr0jtSzaWaX76OlKzqnxzYwwXmIVGWqjQXBLVY6yeTuFPy2TgCXlMqbnC6dqadSVhkRu0o@4Kl/Ahm5ErCefDP4GLRT6JsE/ACS5IA5fYWLAp4uCwEiyA4xcc@SK4oOYAj8RIA/CIxwZNenV1NXNHomtffeWzWg24felgPxKFHtBn4YqvZHbkvkzfXeyMXIN8e4w9PPji4Pjg8Kn88OAYmO9vMS2TliPR6@vr7mSdgqwGOzw8jCDpAZEqo2L46zYbjUbk2wL79ViPDGevyjCiaZKWkTKqpGbwf4dBw//94TX4a/iEUBktwk9qWXgmJZygKkXev38/pu0E5QPbD/YVaNkiurMI9oEHQN8fqNyYy0@NaTRuBOf0axFaPq0Dxp1G8KNe9dPIhjLxPEGVCU@h6QDXbfYYdxH7Djtx@G7VHaO9AmK3zz9Pv@s6IFz9@jA7un3GvR6a/Oz2xOuRjspbvYHp91dAPB8O8LyY4f4vi2Fv0IIM4kIKB9iBh2s5zjKAAnt@tKKUTyaqVnCnAulaAfBnB589Opl5n@xt7z6K5NnO4dOHC69cAJRjj/f2TybWAvcNg@YmUXxr7/HjRWvwAnJaIXl6jeUKqRSMSvDAd4ouesuxlyGIKq9mV3RfB2m9zrKnFf96U33wQI0pR49Rwj9yod4tRwEZ/r208YVUK1ZcY@y/T9oj9rwEhLC218cP1brVnVgXSHnPqEPfPEXxHqoJOA3LkCNPcMtkSeXnf0wvQsfw8NNY@Bk8P4LHvTv4@Wucf2nhd6hHQ7bSEV7ohEbX7PVhBLlwQoBIS9cZ3B97QfhZkRwq7FYHn6dBbjd8rCXguE5vdlk6IhNN0ErFXLGU0YqpYqmYzan5XC6laim1UCyUgH6n1aKaL@ZKaqqYLWWyMMCAb65UiESB8JpdRYGhVBUEeJchWruNX3PYwM9iOHK/FonyWS/2NqGL0LIT@4gJBoQR8Ltink@7wtfNqqBl8chGRmUQo87aLLq/v5ve3xeEHbTgnPxuWhA6aMkV0@nCjiAY5LMLg6AmCA4PA14A5nNLOr2zKwgjHgHqhhGEPlr28sjjC4KJlt3t/X1M5zVaNAwPYGfch1us0FIAMBstmQwJCYLwZhIdwG3zhLKU0z20YJros899dsFPED4L85NOQwzPOByP4VFY1u1tQTjglu1t9PmcCp7jWf0GWrbpEgQXLICEgtADQ881DFsQWmBEVBSENpjalzq44ZczUF@I7euCcMkrCKtIEMYErbfPBGBmA3dM5tGjR3rf7xg9fl26/N2GrIGPOR7t7bc@@6zV67Xcy@29z56hz@efP9JfX47cVq8VBGs14XIgDPicDS4XL8jjQbOpW0t9vgE@9oJP87JpYN6a@hvIU3D1MJFB83Pw@Rx8xksuHhtcAwBt4bUzgPeO3iKf8CIfeo9bLaGCiOpfDg2c68M@c2YDLUgN9LbrVNA@rq7FE/HUZT2fPq2QMxskxKt05Rp9uwn6NiPSRPHqsj6upk9BwClowbGShNAYazlTSK0NNtVSrrymb6paNjkuo@JfpxtncUndTKgP1t8mnoqbWiZbFhqbm5JQV083NbVYzhdero8EQSzjczNTKL9NpOPAiOJDrBdONwu5mRCFQlJXtHKhIFauoSZ8GJhaI99oNhOJC0M/E0XMK3IFkH8qJrukIpqVbmKcGld5ptilWBlX1Qo/sc7SN@LqoMqUEX4AjcfYg@jGm@kykuKEoJaKAqSvKAlRRGqE9APer16Ei0CT14xhzsgvmZUl/vVEtZgXZTyg0HS6TfqCFHs1C4lMduQFniaik8Thpj8STbxy5AR5chwAdIZqmVr4wVY6uQ4CIlfzw/j8h1ooRSK1gC094t@uqQTWzx7tysCpBjZUviLv43e6HVfG78v6cz5cMUjodAKjmPzIwK187dBtl5/xlffGIILgOYbKlfRCup4NcQzcN08DjzlU6JQ7HhhGLTRmh@nVGpj0DktQ@kwXL6iczVqt2qwOjMHQvwTJiK8iQ6nC4E9HA7bDOCyePgrPXjSrO1AB6YqNmtgMtMbG0XGk1kE9MzvVnatRGZnK64pRpa@QC1E8sbVpV0e2p3eNI8PFw0IHhzA2G3gqp91/1dhDwF2o7KtrqeYye1qIA4/X0eToB2XoCjMUeDSr6evKbK4TulRriZVetY6g7/CxIQnCqSTV352CiFWJ1KD3VS6jetUbtfin@tItkK7ylTG4qYVspc9a1dbLccWtDkEoYBULanFG1mF6heDfWTCQNuVmdTytjUy1roG0k06F8o@GO8FSWrqU0lQYSWGEhZBwF8CehVuFG/xVlI4SVkJgTEilx2lZTamGmgJR85XZeSWmfGfPhhZJl8vYMNCoZIW3zsSktm4lOg7TNyRqY@jiFcq4nuqzoQmPBIR7ZugWBRBFiSWkN5v5ZC4tipU3kGs3lujIO@JmttJJ7LCmCA7AG8CtsXy20q0mXorzdSxWEmti1TPeUH0iqaDKGK5BcwQSoDca1NNsLa@mrqSmdG3pnh9TC1q5PorVJRVKm37X2xC@qgmn0DTXLAK/2QUcYD0q4BaSBc6sTNmNqdsQWU7LgFZUS1olAIkMAyKVEBL4GWe@8TQRjxe0eFyMV3DeYQ3cAyJHFCkO5DH@QN0UgN0RykJJA8lyhrjdyAIXp/Ig9F1HOqY3ZCBYRa8i11fXG7N7ab7BLi/1pBRaHzDWS8YiTKFldbkZZWtkkuQaTQ9tV7d7z7YrAfT2biRapo1j010@rBGc1JWUtY9dy09u1F7ydwP3rUCqEdI8VGengXSoZaDMnRk7lM@7ivBa5ds5lI1kTWlEBIH6Nl8OLOZEnlP2PkpK/NnuVTcgSuUnKGCyhF7mfbZ@Kr5/alpXxYxUIwkywaLvk1AjkgS1oLyPwrBwTRUd7jT7xistB1VvO6EDSKM@ED8YRXI5AadgjFdseFx6WXhZfPnk@eHzw322lS4Xy8WZhmhspVJqXI1vsC1gXs1neyCvvGNOTn1vf8533UUr0fIwnsnGM7PBqtFxNRsu8ybUWk1SNzS2CRjKykCXumpeSr@rcXSrkUdeA58Pv/Hj7HijCHYNGMQy1GQuqdVq6romRocfvv43eIzrau@L7ccsjofq//bPfqYV/vbP/jmtKsavK@imZQpRgESjmi9Er66GV1fXcHG/XPQ0yvOULYhg5uvdarSmBM5qQRWjnsRtkN1c1HsXaNlIaOki@O0ecpuQh1qMlqKRaPHJq3eMbYAgWev0eqZGJkWZE85iZRC84M/e48TVe2ntFVAVz4spuP2xhMDhbMt6rVZbp12R8VoSjyNqOZryr19XTvlsCEoj6zb9DG8df8bLicO654E9tIF1fcNguZrKQHxRlA@/8bualv/bP/vthviu@a75TaCzpVIpr2rRX928ooFiJA3yYth8a2wZD/ZKRb7HH8n3a49/ZT0830hf2AY@mVTdePSZVsu0zyAAcgZgxm@3AitRZvc8TBkJBu63eLonMLd0z8hnQ5t36eG@dJwnxMONXllReqbfH7XoNOOJe3ngH9JZDwXwxwSpn8wty2kpAx1nG@iDXR6IUgCB@t1HtgKjJR7VoA@aIveKaiuapHsKitZpAlgTi5UQyxEGKQ/x6HVj3O0KdGbbsDrHxlAnHUPgHx5sPeggGGqgohPh4WHkOc5qchKZatxg8V2@IV@iI@UOMTRePDyESFXLSN2FgUdEBDwUHRxtor32gow2/Ea1EO6zB4iug0poQ3j6jPU0wOSr1tMQWEbUyBLwD9XZErEklT8ZZgLnlbkD5WNqDRKdOlBClBuXmSnd7ZF2NRv1U0FaCWhWGZVt1tXyaYpznFWV6pvOvpuo0AfYeNTwQiXBCiWVo13TBaZNLc7ofiGWjULOliNZDXICgLxB8Kw3qhbDkwtO6zWpYgrUUCD@yaFfcPwf9ZeR0iFAfDtQs8suWqZPADDAEQCGVHp4JohXUWoOVVujHh62wL4gO25PMT1vZOQKxSxlSMcT3CEoMLlzoJoS6P5WKHN4YHpSipLfZ5ZxblikkiDINiqZ0nmnJDzDvTWoVxJZ9bxIqANVOVdSqIVEKcXdHu7tP94@2XuYYpKaQ3A88dZ2JrCJmcrl3kny71ojrx@gEQbh3Vdu5bMcyRNeKr6lxMUg61uz1Z6czXAYAX6iC6cGh4l4lYK5xgC/h8YjZkO9g7QqRWHseHCqH4/T81NjpodZGbkW4k1YuWHPj0YFRGlMK4oo6PkdCBV8bB7CYMECDgdsQHhuAK2kFVADAXVr@oCRqLOEMFdYdvwdCKsk1bhSBmHXwg8kxlG/1iy1jVPf0Vn8BJWzwxBPpG0tTnQB1T70q/FPvXilDcx7yFmw88RIvApKYNpdzEWCV9yJs3MZtl9iFJzHEaBCRGCPxckBnV/8eRy4jUl8npXwxatz3WVvq4Ch1ONkTtT3LDr3mIhznb0Q7K2MPEhwDq7qVyYBWk7nUkaVhHZnt29ancTb2TSGwHCa3UQy2a5WM@IVJOkOgTh5QyCGBop0YgXdunNuYCHtOQml0bAhf/K6bVywL588fgRN/sygY@71l6frMSUFDK5YwSLo1QQCPTx8cqS7nuGK8hDf@xPhKYGfNAkSkaG1B149fUq5TwlYNAV7IVDOnuEHpfd2Lk/03lN9YCTiepwfMMOkTGgUc0OXuZRUMZNJEYqo183TuTqqCvONK4hXvSpB9V2jW2lBRZ9Vrr3qeaInVnx49WeTyEESVU2j2H0IVPXgsVDrJn7g/NHJk8fV@IbOMNbqkl4RT7YmyAGIQghDJ@e3XVe/nEMdoCqEVT4/I0oIA1cyLtTmy7Kh6LU4MK4r8/PYIc0WsizHpwjcSYxSAca51ZtNWnGnWHA5NKrowIe2z/ZOhBSEdUeGiI42Dm@XRLS4@oNqmAZHN6QUNAReHiNMtZp98IDcuOqTalVLp0VAzco1xOYB5iYmwo9buXb1aicxqUh9aC5RtaDJmqLb3gXqKQcWOJ0rbDouDBHVDvCQDzwgIVXUxX1u@pcPPMC2aqi24QE/f1pdy64XD82db35ZOs4/TLRbn6tCSnjtOTYIau5wNgOufiFztghorNvm2EWZQJ2lbV0Z6meOku2k28V0US10jELOKKYzxXbOyJRawCW2u9liq1Mq6IVcu6XA4OZTEHlg4ie0BI7@mGz3fsmuYsyKIPh3uypw751cqVvS0plMtlXMddLZbLeo6plMvqMVW6XW7VzbND8odIV0F8eORQr86WrmLnKDtgehxf8B';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,R@'_  7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:_a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111  >252O@ xxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D//> ++++++::@_        / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.---;-._       ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]x<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@//:@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];t}?1&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rext~+nu U9583>Ehar Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2]putsngt=>+le.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8           \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3           \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Ahead spec](https://ajc2.xyz/projects/ahead/spec.html), [list of commands](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/ajc2/ahead/Head.kt).

Ahead ends up executing Befunge-93 code. `R` command is used to separate Ahead from Befunge-93 (`R` is not a command in Befunge-93): `>77*,68*,R@`.

Ahead code is on line 3: `>252O@`. `;` under `O` fixes LMBM.

**DOBELA**: All generators (`:`) are switched off on line 10: `.^`. But on the first tick generators above line 10 manage to create one dot, because
commands are executed in reading order. This doesn't break dobelx64 somehow, but it breaks [dobcon](https://github.com/stasoid/DOBELA). 
Answer 251 is also affected. To fix this I added underscores after colons above line 10, on lines 2, 4, 6.

Answer (score 4):

## 253. [BrainSpace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainSpace_1.0), 11600 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTJEQCIMA3KVKvlk7rTHdL01KfPnNINRskQRItEGADoES1Wl0zk9RcT@zKdSZzXePxjc/MJE7sJFXxTd1cTyp2ucrzNeXKJ/@Adr6kXCnPP5istTbAl0hJPXGqAhLAfqz9XnvttfZjoaV7/V/9KooXO3Ksy57l@Mw3PJ91XPPccGW2c8m2dNPLaZlIBKG23d5oYNi@V45EmcqYbVywA7ttdsCN@c6ZYZtvDRf8NMaGrtNz9QHz@7oPFhNCsYeG9W7wzmdtZzDQ7Y4HkBnGjnTw7I7aZ0xveb6rt33TscEry9hz29IHrY7OAMJwh67hU/Q5BlG0zyjMvE@esSeO6xmYfNvwPAcdC4xtGIOhf1kDSxEgdNd0Hm8//WwhcImxz3TI2dAyxgt5UdPshWm4nYUQqsq@ONnfX3TV2Dckx2b7N/OnZthz19MtfTH@LNse@c6Bv@ieY9s9w9aZJpdkbdEzz3Zc/UaQAnMNvdM1LUM27TaTWN@whobL0IV1HReazDesYrqYbm5PQ8ptDFucei5EWw0vprs9DzydcwOMBrTE0DQ6rOs6A6bb3gWkpJbSU3iMtjSPDm3IICAae@1B6I7BPNscDg2fe0JxDZe8IWVmmfZZhGPfket0Rm3T7gGcAfU6HPlUJi/ShmA1NgxwWEYDi1ItcDDIwrEzMGbbwgPkhVx7Q6Ntds02rxxj7Bu2B@X1ZGZC212YlsU6hgUBprG3U8xz2MibcWpZel9uyxGsXEyFDc4sZrL2cMi4FxQDsrSfLjJj4Lw22Vvwt/oeGw8HzDMH4O23nW7XMNhbY9iH4GzQiXScCIOrPVwo2cQWMwDGNqB0u0ffgnrzsTrtLmStw1ozcJAPyjOVWLcdqD6X2fqAY0N7eEmlh2gmIbqOI6N7xzE8O@6zC8c9Yy2jrWOxMTHP6HX1kQUpml1sDsAD02MDB97QiDaDbEFgH@sC48bEIksLgsmEzWsMoWNi8zqILtDWYStfuDrgh@sF7eibA8AO0497zNA9EykWBPEMu0OYMZzQMgdKO9vo7NyEjgdVMXIpbs9wCfUpXoalgCj1Ca4mLlzTB4zAUmyzI0N32YlrGCLHU8Nr60PE0tkkITEHU/CxIDIh5sZGfO9wPw4IykPI@hAQ0s2cfPPziM7kKos1K3BXBaES2Xv6kF3FGmjmNBOQeOgmdJFV3zNPaTQMuMdqS@m51xGINQK1YjHFGfqKLg0hg5IPGVR0NKJJOtfkoTWTMNtYaIOZbsOhOtAaQATYFykqWXvkukjdp5Wqn0GhLcfuQX1CYd2RzZs8n4YmAPzreClmnBuIA7yNnAuq4ZM@YAj8AXSGsvABhyoUhhzoikGNhul6jjUiOAjp@dgfoVYgKMZ40GVfsK5uWhgE/DEqnmvX8AA5MczI7mDLD0zb6MgszAZRHRf64jkkp0Ok5AC9YTBDWyhTAAwN4VBR0evDb/9ep9eDeLbbbcftBOj6BSB7m4ZGnTILgxtDhHVs3aJsAVwKU@fBIYFz3TI7ROV0@zJIgjJBqV44I6vDqKNemNDl@joQWwMIRNs3OJI7Ix/ymGID/YxTRJNjLhR8oLegYSkBSpuKLbGtXWilNnRzwhlpMPK7RSYN91jcU14mNsuJzbWGAZkTZXE9pii9CiCcvE5OYIvfhjlfbM8NFZ6ve47ZiQwv/b5ja0xqM6FddYaGnYjPxRFPxd1WXJSRUifEillty13T7iTiG4CLNUg4Llba1XbdLJ9WFoLPJgnRXGA02F2NRFsUkNRQpzhXBsBcyEDJvpAC04yf4zWxytFbnnHGill0O@cOUWJdEC8dRBCgQ7JnGcYwkZZVEckEwi0tN3osK@lCHEGBy@ZpMh6NJ2eLTjFASecKip31xHSQbFnDPvIbUCm2NwSa6yLutnXAHg8HNR9YuhRrEV7TSAiUhWjihREHqt0CQhriEXVJ3uUwvISEMohh2oXme7LRmenIQASgL/veDWpsOcgdUJ5w5AHSYWOieg@aBgLzgmzzgvCUyGW@SGc2EBSMrWWwotQyoRNgdwOaHuD8TNkAPKNxGIiNd5IZ2jPQL3FU46zBtMPgmKazAZAH95K1DaQ5QHwMPqBgIiPqfx7wvczpsrSk5XLzfexGF/NdZVv6Coj0W@XWnoSFn@1MSGhYF9hsS7d7I70H9MKxIYjebhtDPyBUUBLPB1K0ON6QoxQMnrLXj8S2FtOmQSRkj6ZpIJHnrRcMhTpSl4Btl4AnQ9aPywKsY7pAlmAkX0gdAM4XEhdeIchcBl4JK7IQcgCAZMbYaI98oGqAwBd9s90HnMXc2Zwu8kFoMXlwmk0dKLvUnSSNmVFrD7SIrEycMBsro5CwRW/GA4MrRlWbc6DGn3W4PWbdGyyJ2JlkEQaCGVdZ0WXAvTviHDi2syRSqMhJtAgy78PbATixY2SKYeAK2S7qrBNOedJE0GZANaDnA/71fX/olWGcMP3@qCUDpign7uWBf2gjsii@e2n6Dje3LKcFZNmD/qmEKSjtUcscLxSI3CZt@NqLnAMD1vVYFUbuNyPAukS86wHBJPddBJ7xEohwUxT8KQAgAclQUYmuR6R4H4jK8aXdTghzSCmkmIB9VxDBgAEnVfM5Mm/z2XwNTou5RLDZzMgKQime2yaDNMOTYvQITtmKfDJXtHvmMfKJIMCjq1ueAW97ZFloHdmcyiU4ryCyq8gnnwBpS1By5mBomW3Tb3Jf9uBBwFOwNZDxkG3qIs8kQphPAmFaBoICMMHww6Fl3zkmZjchQkE@uZ5L2HBdx@Xp@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@xFjTK312eH@3rMqJdPXvTPgKaQewirAK0OtuB0ZqIE16hiRZTBANsDUnuYE5w4w8V67zSSHEZjU5pmYGS7abEVsQGuI8XSYZA3mi@D1Ib@7c2WgSMidQt7Gv7TDLHHwpXmaJLkPFHv3@PHcFNngDPgJ1vYsZL4llxcArMo6d@zQayJjlNkByWg2MJiAW8BfdiZzAbZjS0gLQ3HOmU2IT4gABLkht4WchDkHgxF3zTGIxFGcTwlYf@RYkfvfdWwQTg35BVFDgQEhx9kqQ17K/x9xRkpue9PeCZw@GIeW3gZ6Px9dQ2ANiBAokKIs9xErNyJeFA5Ijr@rjMBKtXUb669jkpw6Mr0@Vi/IEjgKuF2oVRRScXKHau2AtYHL7UFNG2PT51Ir9PBjDPJI9xIiyknbXM5ALEMeGTMVztwRA@u0QcI3gFdGXz5dwvbsc9N1bKxkeQ@iBlJUwTZYiHxZ9QIabW8faA9X1@@yyKHGbjirM3U7G@ti5bY96F22Yzk9h60DAKKmLHPEPrBxhhOkHF8fQo8y31IFbfccEPXncdAwJnOm@cxE3tQRUiF4@TWMAmx5oacAK8p8fPDVHrAhai6dhvyHtjRdk0LOxLJYRnRssylAsApgId5gS35lDPuX7hw6eU4wb@LT5CF1TD6TpQMLCbkKevhbCjrbybkL9PPQqxOalpV9j2QCnLyblavnSj/HrfBuAyWMLjija1gVc5HeaPBp@yLhaihzdGsyVSB1B46vK1/IQKLxEUEOWTKZ4CnxtbgiSfgUyItpNaZ0jHMFqdQ05vGe0V4a99gw2gr64uDGQsPS6gk9V1RNAy6bHlBM/g7rYBJysfy9ZBIJO@VukjbPNAzyJ/2RETHafYcJDRAxZksmwADRB1lZgpoHBhDlkkmwYEUo4jsjEOs6hmUOTP@A5uwtG2UXmYi3jFQr8N0FejON4Mg0gCHnEw7TQQbn1adjlN3j8M@AklOsIOLLvEpdo6OsT2N74jguyJUeU2lOQZtU/SDwUBxv2JH9MUTAQ@3R@O6F4/zTw4d7zaPtk0dVZeS5imW2gEZ0jOYAhFkLusOKC/OGM4R7gDum7QxMKFEY5dsz65nj@Jx5wIWD@11RDBjG8fhh8/HBzrPtZ98KMkcjujkYWTrmsRxbAJjEcUwwt0bTdloO8Bb2aGVMwFwc7hw@DmP5/Pnjg@3mw72jw5OZaF6PLFNXx8rwrLeqQJ8jCFPlNK/6Q6szv6JDYurcLEJAbFDmqjCQTZkkwVNCN54oSmUyeiCLjMOjJOEssI7z3C7T1HSp1GnpxaKR77Sz2UJX73Y6WU0t5rrFnJZLw6OQLxnsHYFLkjGmmRsw8VkRnEDCNCDz9FLlbMjhgCjaBo7lcmm@Jr63ZK6dyxmFbEkvtUulkq4VOhldKxYMI1/oZtNpI6@mu62iWszcmrmZbCBrNbUNaAYIeh1OFpAnEL8EvOa6A8888HoXrKNpWr6d65YyWieXznZapXSu2GmpBb1VMtLdbEbV1E5bU8thWJxRBSrRhwZDrtIG1jT0klTwFCPhYDrbxLTKGC5DBwQnlkESMwyXkVFwCDyy6DEKFpFxajZwz6F7uISMUzSBex7dB7iAPOVkyTpxDACLBIjryLLbCh1L6DhZQZ5bWwVSGdDPZf6rAwUxX6npa4z8AtegZ8p3parkfu53u3POGjmfSTiUWVPnDDnzFej5td@gsDe8lgJP4stSfHzleml8N7yWAk/iy/H4cMV7eXQLPstAJ5HlKTJcIV8a14LHEsBJTAWKaXZVfepXJL9VS@pBWku9VwaaxF2iuPlqefM1X61oBovliM28g5wAJ/bYAf75sYnz9t25HhOZSOCNiBBOI8xPJE19tOkyCZPOl6/vCLMRcWJg2mcOCc4TUzMtqzmMZRLF4My6GbILogY95kBvZOqmDx@/Bq0uPZYA4KC7ODNHHjTtGQz9MNTqyjN64QToshzMT@XOJd8yuiOQgpSWaaP5DjCpVCTIbqtlrgKFmsDNB@F7CViZPRuBJKrJWVkNxV5cOgGazedhTw4OCbClkxA3P//P5irfH7k@hAre//nbHWiEm03U1y9JFpwYmrZxQfjRXdliQVC00GN5605HfaoYMt0VZVvHJVfdmhiWR02tL0l93R2gyBU0NyAoPgATbsE1nnM@FxO@lydSZlTJ8@sMzDYHrL0EmmAXlkR4YiRkW47eoWrgorBpUCAXG5s3gzHmQuEMwwMjz6qElqxcsOlWAb8/8kf8ibsD7mpGc4j3bV00gEzn9JZqAIust0zjlkZ39bNRx5GA06MiY8byS2CnpafJOqlr6Wfc2ETj8uLzArpmrwf8RPBeBXbRB9mGhFLlgl534YVnj7yh1ILG8qHjkI26wuCWFFyLP1eBmMH@uYlhda2ZFj3u0egT5CJ0AZaOKhq3NEkzlWYuVLOlty5RVO9/PJZhgsTgAM2ptpPJdAaHvcna7@xWpNXhcayk8KXS8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyB7olaZ0Z40qKHk4dT01LQGneRmpbugeo5QfNYZxD89HjNnTHkakNYpc7Nd2C7NPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVtxzI97NrWKgq6uAA3TRO3s9FjZkraXFaxHeKZvL40MS2nC07bx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoGc2RnVaW1nQu8V7IWfefc4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs710ROm078JU3A5Ej@X1eLY0X37bWuo@3wfCKY5ZAe2eeO2ZluOxY3reVi09F4Lx53KMnq1BU7clWg@aNS8PFmRqyORglnVFu@pWz7HyxZ6iw2Nl44/cLo4Jwfu@1G9CvVT1buoV8keOrQbvlWT/THHP7mo7WppwcdF@xnjLCLyMhAWLkqsLCJIE7sRZXrj9dJFCygqXl1c1gNvuX@iX4fvXGFlW1W44sgwvid8G9g8DlIpg8F3Og/86qWVvT61zP/J0I9rCXYWYadwzy4CBjJ43mpRpafUjQ6jp9P2JVdcaGSNjKa06bL02cH/7LVLI/TOVDooRC2Y7cUYI5zonUG8D@fFeucYxHG23EhjdMqGT38npLKV3Q@DRhyhyH4HhCA03A/bs0XCuceekOPvZ7TXXH4Y92@nMZRJ9PpYiFe/mp@YYec@g@1bhiguDuLZVzaTT6YC/mZm/nrPcJnRlJmFfm/w5lzC5TFOewuJsiDtjXJ7GdCoVmt488ySc1LwfddJWzQgQcKmk2KZt@Jf4XNUky6hty3Gsj2lCILodE/k34Epx4eeuprzBGwW7wdh07sPDmZNWd9WsBx@QAukUag8F79uwYXbq9V7NLOGSNfTS3oL19nmgmYncu1KBYZ4ml/jWCWs14xnMqKhyUS7c2iM5O@u0DEvnr3E@e1t8JTlza3wTliXgk2ltC9fD@ArYdEU1ukC3hpdQWWYHhJy@MTDIeot0oHdej7zwtRJo7OC9xFum9cZV4YYmEAobn3OrbTOslO/YIJb5utszUK6xcFU8cF1FnMNZ9aWVezDQewY/V3Ub9ZxOdeDWYS4NTo3LJz3KfNdZG4LxrR@3owJ0pjPj0gvfSyN8ctmG9hwN7p6qW@j3bdqodFdHl5Wliwl38Ip23@nbfaPPdwJNbKu6B2Ckz0/E3VYIyH@v32ZEn2Z3Kc3WrOVY1n1qFukjp5aO012apz08p9WBoB8V76XeAo/gdecUIIz1VEE06K/qN31jBEOW5/jO0JDItgrUwski/lxFRcPFnV93FurWGQKokfD968Z/p2za0x1/OKRXc2iNPHpQUImO1y1ryn1K5j5YYfp82xHHW6PntNp9864stQzdt80zJZwR4tZbJdvhTC2YTHqIzrJlQuW5lzJiQ3XW/xhfB6uaNJhc4sPWxLC8jctsd@S6l1gTvuMwz3IupvRhfv/EZBqXrz6gYVUOgpXBJd7EDeDOunAH2S1LIMFC4koEIyYcGW7JSAPDoq6cUZrb3jnTOzIZ/ljFFy2UnzI1s377MVOiwbYHmhw0Z2ZuwX0Of@YWo5cOVnZ/1PNukjs@Yd8BFgsfS1t6u4dnmhcamjcqjEC6HbxW1bdmKbh9G95NaLmRcevqSu7W5RWCUy1Jd0x4NeEFbThaOW1mmUOPP5nU1ZYyDDeXkG9CXS4Xm4P26RhdvhaCprs4vYHj4iEiYCmktmt4bZxKR4rM@SdOfWynB5RZstgUOIRdWoSbq9ZLm38y4klfPjV6Om6vfGziTktrCVZArIuL13dF@s2R7pnfHDm@sTS@xQXsu6J7ovfM9qO5mg8jC2s02IPHX3Noj043K/@ib3p0fiM03DLnhEjG0RbxrAn8/jJpbWG6fnIw@vZplRlGKdj7zaQDFu4RnxhwwQD99aVpLZuJd4YkN16S6bZJeNOnmdngvRSrlm8CuC35i9FgOPKC1/LUaZ/O7BT14IzcvQsTyKL0Bqgx6@uWv3wae2ZmFniuYJCcGldx4V@ZltNjXxXTDFg0GLSRKV@CcDswXB/pPvQIewkCU9r3XCjFSQ/J5QV7AzhhZJhk2qZ/@wSP7@sgI4VvLAwfbPAUovIYn/LWx8YgnSyvkce3cjAwtl@2LTwU/7GSACe7gIXHdGgdjZNz87N4HyRj7AYRhqOLbVzMymu3LvqUcUh17JEv4S7/28aU/K1jSpmNi/kZ1GCJb@49eS7OYghtf72LDzVAEBx51uXUtHLjwQLimTYwa6tp8Tx0KE08NEilwTPaqHlHmO0hnp4ikv/QWSbxHF3C6HNvkQkGkNHgodHGlcc7037qPAHWDYayIRDdwTMDtwws0JLlATHYY6etW1A/nTuTOaZol4wVU@FaHxotaF9ralrOiy2L@KHu6yt4J5o4JAlwYroTV0yrZbivaUZwxrxKqJ3P0CNjTGLIaoThvVDy223OcOO03FwfWVzb8YaOY/MnEeE0vNQntxMbGB7ocf8Vdxn3L8@NfkuFtPnSHp7z7SZGhx/cW1Vc12g5Fn9iEVaQA9vkmwt01zQ85bFpj8bkxiTg3ZaLOXwbb1ou4DSH14fOdmGCjD3Z3Yub1fhWYW9BkgKW@Fz3aMl/uUwzt5P4/ruK@rrbdnDtLDB85MrZzJGwO@j4ZKs035rQgkYZA0HT26NQr8AdWbUGrQE9VsokMy39zGjhkbsWnR/19fEyJnL@6FjguHB4KyRp2PHzLHEEUo9490C2KLLN17g5pAcR9IulaBIm99Q02m918Q5aOulFNJes6CTRLu1I85vggM2xDMnv4x5LxfdXEYyn5tmoc4@1rnABZTQwcM16fuVmJVI5Xp8wwlm@Sj8huK4RbN3GXYLQ9UMzUl1peyXKYvTwP9z5XIGBuZnP4gn@0VjqATm7e18AZH7k2sHrPmh35Hh@1xwfDlGNk@Ouoi9YrBwEgRfvDmhaX1UIaE97ZPH5jt7Mjq5Bh@Q74Aa7DpgsIuG@IRn2uUQqjsbhcqWrh3pkVrbh4uZQ9Y7doRfeZD0QPKShR29l6B0dPD48kYeeesvMIW74G5kWru5RVkI3KCCZVk9RH9NetVsKEhx3Ic08Ex0OXio4iAVuphsc9vbkUM1UcGqNiFB4fgIc9XZ7hPMl0JAyI8BEQk8mRTEShHrkXLAB6rDBQB4dvjwzhxWWDo2Yyz6MMwSPx88TLKazjSrTMmkmihWuyQH4TqjpkVFhXTOMetvzzJ4NWQhzQEp4UEEH1@/jMWBm/TDeep3FrsbldFm9ZlUmlAV2espzjBclsjcekgadZzx4PaafVmNxSYrH4g27zNLxCbhhgRC3FFyfg4XM4ivI8KR@uXYth1RjTWqzwhWQAHFF5T593e5YBntu0@IllN/lajS4jpYT3JT7iz/sBDqPSLfXwPR0CyoE1ZY5A6PvXGzydMPqGg511JmEcYA8bnENHtLuNgNh0G/3uaojaK7n@yfFQIFKoCMNLEd8Sm2SC445uK6Hh0F9jhg8N5ODfUHCk1BhoUDKGA1sGNY7ft@T2bFJ5zxH7vTkRqA5zvZdnLzvpNgB6xi4/5GO79JaleU4Z3SkB3Pyiz/kamPoEG9wuDJMntRFzaSIZ3VV0tXSbjsjyHUYyVvDdQKQBFYySOAjXBkmbWXkLuLRVtJnA9guhdpcKBmu0mV3@5hJeyyOetBQ@0LF7CZi288@@6KePq2@ZwPF@M/fVsSroOKET6VS3hNSLASpXCNizXrnwHvqG2dCbCzwBCcnnM1Ajrjg7YE63DiS4SHnEMccZxh2G2RMSQHVBBsDxQ4JNFM7h2pdBqTMixDWuCC1LnSUzkZKScrkPOhgYBUpat7rqrHEiC9WSsc@y0GCqBpHBxNX/0VnflFFCQaJjdk7RtQMOFM1lwYbr0gLteIMqjvh7vjM7KkF5aHRGtHO3XNN1nJVKk6sWd2okQlGPge1U9VfNsZaWmqMC3unwGsHldpojD9Na19CrTsuhHqgYM/be/rwKibX0u/eefolE4TreIWfsgAyEbs6OjjaOz7ZPnl@DK1wHZK2fX7WKqQ1iEV0fLLvWKT3C@oFmd6PoD8T25QMomZJUYzMHnQj0KCuBUmIceMMaZoLfUfwZeE9Y8b/JkBA07omi0xGBsACnZANaw0LPxqi9jIWhA00MBGWmTh@YAeaVAyeZVlCS6mqBFaFypKgsu5ZVWx1YTe5231q7M5Ybq@2zaUgWGOT9OoTf17EpVVw/XdS7qHuef/z5eax3F5ugrml3AA6cQ3D7G8fPH7@bG8@WDjIE9WtlnLBCU9OnLGnccY5VDlFihWCgLjYWxWYQAG4NRjMuOJLw78woFgBcWwPeGDCUMq/EJkiJtRMFXWvngZcSCJBOUD@BhmRxQOowNXOZDEco2eiu@JFnBCBfWESdZhxWQhijpIOURmvsBgYa1BdYdc7IiIe0Ou4N8v@pMIeh0XDMXrk8T63YqiajDoeg//MqBSatFM2ZsFwpp4yiWlwW4bdgwKHsGKFj1EsxitCiPG8C5P8ou5HyFPntU7rK3SwIji4CaO0pQ@9kBmMsqeOb5TZm5FDyiFCYjLhL0jtqM5VtVLTcgWkpHQCBFpgfcNxi@I72D@uInfGWTOi77M4N7JxoAIgrjU1OL7tu6hdmJ@r5eoLeZU7gaa8cKikOQov0Iw14RI8dm56JkjY1Ahd5HEsoJRYmqDgqHmX1IKwbcsDnqQDwzdwKD4OtcCcyHTajx/5k2wmRAEn5QnLmGJCBGG96k3NaTCUXqDM9YoHjhEcxezNxBnfWJMkqLmeaYdqdsuod5fE8zLz3RFu5qvFbwQJs1Amk9T3B9YM4BIdkg1D@fDbv8f1RjZ8MH8/MI/TO2D7zcDWBfNvhT6qCrZ/MrFpYPsBt71UsMluKsub5nOi92Dl@UhAzi3hRsGQMIQKh6lAkybH5v7i4Ih5bdRjiw060MczbYVkJpRTmDkAzDinhkZwnsK0HafxJOpfAJ4AcgGSII@DbA2lZ7inCdSbVlYUzDguu8i0q9IY850OpEbtzQjVhwInpuRz@ayqQCal8zBC0uzSw0NePEJRLANhjJybw@qrVpttbGwwwWvrllHNVziCKDH9ZUZ4NcloDGAjXFqoMwgDQaYhwK8WBEvE9KQqYlAczeJqHAlbx@H4BixhggwAIqKzHeqCAJ7TCaoKkNk2xj6xTZehFARU23Zm9AaHEUkQEY8blVwu9snpwS2cK5zppfJsMwgvEIyE5bKwDGPrL1nDb9ingbJTBtj3kyX4a4P5Hy3RgMoxC3Xd3FS9mVhUnImlYVvHtoNTrvuQW5bQFC2jqHlxBkOFICrIL/b3dxAl9HCgGG3DfO0Mve3dvYPPD4@Ob6hgIsj4IlicxWsbyYYkp@qnE0N8ku/5St3ZV46f7OyHVTmbq@mkJ0JMd7EuZnNZaos5XZH6C35G7mba5HEjITV934hpxkTap93gN2Of@iozgLv8iM6NVBPi1XX9dKPWsKM3kn@3TK1uVF5H5AJTwyOluvHFbGIWJyr0T1CFvieHB8BVPP2NxwJ952x6ljxwmPHg4GEsQAEishJCrSKekIFDPgM0VXqicR3@HpE@PktEyk4nOZqBPAm1/WPXmuroC5TT9XWvb5mtCAzgHVTYyFXLhLpTJkppZG9omX5CjNAUSBXZICBiiUDn/7g8lmmtNkGqdSmuFLtN310YnxiBTgDxxY9GXp8dOcOZua2HRmh6BtwIezjiC3kG@3w0ALguvZ4ZSGIN4E8kCAwVFZ9klUvV0LMCdXfjJKoUhPTqqPQuKLg86OQSY1HuG@OO2QMCnhBT0NM/VYGtmhzIx0KTCjw7DjSO1/BneDRqtko/SuvheBq5Xtdl0@4Y4wSq8SmfAn@K7vGLF@dxUbiBA6R6cTdU1raggzHsiLof9Iip/sKFzlaaKPpfUJJZKqEqJNQtAM0CKR777mMwwviU6A70IUuMSDmox2RG1kQjYac83xWZVOP6RWyWTJJUDS/yAK4ZQbtkIsRhCZyHTChVaB109ewOvt6aQ1ZXZfkUzJSIyGI4o7YLQznORYkRkJIgSJmirWLbsjLmiGOvzDEPwqB/hLSVMdSQucSbdFrSVLiDdUGlZrUHM1qepj2Q12qpVA5aY57UlBigxU0qLysQ7RISEnKpUL/BUXGoNdT5jh8HwJUCIAtb3zBs24AKApwZ6DAG6yNAMldMhR/5SE11hFMKUZ7FR8HZc8jovO7wvfiVhcvJMaVCkzOVaxhTXzVwUO0Gw@ql8vcVWalcJWJW9VIBRkesJWL9qprMrCeTMXs9EbNxqH/wAOd0rmPASTRlEJHGACTFLLEC@AycRzVmV2L6RiLWqWrrFAKsIKRdQYD3niJfxfRrJfYARuoUuLi88yZiHqmfTMuyeg35wx4SU1KAM1eorY@@8IHJx8xkEvMgx5qYgfdK4zhJNLtxrND0USXgRpXeIOhuC1R10hI3vm/CKzBwDhoaCLuGhD3Y8t8MgaeawzPL/FbwHjzhb@CpKkYbOQ1vlv0X5n3uT1gCehcnzWBc2SfX/wkVOE5AJaI1pYsiEJNf/Sqq5pmQiG3mM@fJeC5dgYdaKbAc@zTW0LJRFt0CcV1ZF1zhqvGweM6MrpZ/I0l1vSu/OT06Ozr6Umwk4tHdw5eCmgXQAivRfd@rwLQVF/u4KxpdVyJRZV19UFCUV69eAbsLV70m12ah5FOxLsVP64kCWGqFwnoqX1xPPduKNzErYkLTxGNmmgprmEOv04Hb6dN3dhJRfrHNTUwLDPBngdtg3OVu08xwkMA1DBt63QFXbuq5KGsUdH09mdW27IqspbVf/HztOnV11Nz4xXcGirGGr0N8ff/6CZqP1dyna2uf7uxksymoPG4@@uroW9vb29mHqdxRPbeZldJrG3/xZ2trmrahKWunnqeexutnXwpaOivIv/hZ/Ojom03Pw/bDK8NUMOKzCLfKcjl2xt7CddZl@Cfz286MWUdzq/sWB0hglqtEbOLxXCZ@/DKOxX0bVVU1ekm/JlXDGlNrm4X/8sPDN1E/WtOUFy68/eibaL4Y5UYwgC0T2s6jtegGguWvo5dKtVoFY@G//DsIX/sc4kGfyw141HJhXPnLaE2qUpB30VoeDKqmQbr/7dvfjkRrY0SE2sE@02raOscVtfhAfcBUfrFGVC1mD7e4j8q2DrWctrGAfIqqao2wPWeaG5t24tyHwkO7MmfGbdLuIWZEWYANZPgYOPwkU35t69VDRanBUItXubzVaIZZZIWi4DjQnStge8wdK4Hn2JEkBwI4yUZFwisoQrRYTTV58hNcjc4YFgo8ebKg7BP7R8Lt4fWX/99f/ugvf0i/H9H9nyLRcLOFVD@vndb4Bc0n1JA@scD@xGZP@GXb8Ic7tKILOoDJZtOyRKO1Gj7oH9jIRO8Ft8CnNrEQxDTILXABzaB0I9H3isLK2DzntcnFi6CwiZ2KwHNNhiczJZuWDVFgE641@NEfrokVn2vkEjgTyM1rjdVuu26lvpFoPVo/PR1vsNlIbo8Qr2cyYpsc2EJcjZ5HohKQhmTyGfCMATLD1UjedT2HW5abgU2ReYzRSPTv9KpFWPQKrtOkdH1dl18mK5XgD6xUZWLDi5sgS6fXkrTxspZM1ilr9VqQxw3ptCYzyjHlW26@3IB4kxv1jaqzS7fcxMqR4lknnne2Tl/W6hvzcQTRbG0lsTq3IJ5a7JQBEw9NcL1xXbuub1xfb2zAf4Oe18EbXK83bvzpNb0qK4Am1/UpNnqjrtQaSiNoyVOwy0oNXWSlAYYavAGuXo9ErxBdWP2UFJZVpbqaz51KjLrEOtAppayuaxklN/40v6dBj/cQXBMEZR0N73BkAv6iFIkil17izHqJHF59@Ppf49348PW/AStkDb8MR76tN/h7/BZ/b3z8nbTx9@wN/k7e4u@Zj78jD39PWviLRKuMAXMU20xb6fO0eqaegcFkaeBN@@m@2sHxIW2w9GX6kqUHjtoBkwG/NJjMdJeleyxtp21VBU8w@Czto6kLrx78uhCLCz8zncbI0@cMUrFw1CFFv/R@12RiI1Jn8VcGcDWyKqflvNk8zeWHb@rx00pUaTQUzuYxLVshxc7X16zZ3Hv6sNlUEPEbT5zD6f/wcDBrvfU/OHSeHDoDB/6Hh4dPGkCwasmtpLQFV7WW3Ahem9FaZbNRlhB/5QCTo8rGZqOWkdCcTwJWauiW/MhrGiO8a2uNCEjBL15cVF68wP/FeeWiQoaJlRuaAUAAxg0QijtABC@gZ75ovFBekA2uc4qXbGi8AM/QxA3KiwtwesGAM5/8oTpmrX8Hf/N/r/@T5yxRPxWhD1xdbyToEvEnilfXV9fBsyYmEoElsQE/dAA7Brm6rqGRgK7AVE@Ip@L1NXeDZ0Lc4BHWMI2NGgWeAgKhiE7SpHT5I/F3@8a0@dWIA0MEMmsiWHBrNMbptFhpgctk1l1/R2s3YoV2tcRauN4GcpoqEkQuW6mo69ysZbVKJRtYCsVKpRiYY4lE6eZVS2@q@XxZy2ZFsVJJB7AgklVCI0RheHq7gn28EhUxs7zjJ9I470dfdIgLZeHBg0TwDZDN4RAkdLWUfvdu4tRsdky32UT3zLt3QlPADTDVUg7s6eK7d0Bz4iLI7k8dvvSakFT2qVajFEoglGvZAngzVdGmafZ1T/d9N/HWHKYE3MfnCSJpYU6nHbcR/@UPvvOdRryKWyLINatiBJgKy21s5LO1Wj4L5nwRCi7E@B6bRC9ZUsXrmCLw4oLsHY8GXmqxIJLrdRz9WXSDbdago3p4savrKLUfy@bEROvSEK/AJXRTSyXuyLL5RDFZCn7VNZHV1lnwq9frmWR2vbC@dQoszfyFBLVypVfjihK/rl7pZZwbuq60A03/eLpGf/AgU4KKLKYrjUiz@XD7ZLuJHwnElW8Y@Bg6EnWO4Krm0I3XaSIvVzqtY6FOFaURj5crW9ToajHHovFKACnFgdSzYolKH/W8iNnFg3ZjinfhXo8OmVrIwJgKQ2pkSNuQCmnWwZVclznd7ho4QsuxFi66e4Zlhd9HuHBcq3Nhdoy1SPTo8fbu3klK24ARWtvf3k1px893oipac1M7eWfQ/mxv@@Hhcwhw9Hhv@3jvs4Mv9p4fgbsXef1WNwzdGBnGRXM0uniDKvSNpjEE1@nVNNqmp79@rQ/pYhVOmC8uPvzkex9@8g8//PQHH376vQ8//dEvv/7R9@D@Q7h/wN8/@LelHD5/@fU/@YMPv/9TcPxPcP9HuH/@y69/99v8Jvufwv3nM25/GtwzcPxm0do6XoAPRa2YXE9uQU1uJddLJcAL8tmIQHK/@cuvf/izX379Wz@G@58F949v3r/98@X3j767@sZwP/yD22F@8O/g/iMeVwj7g9/nbvi@Af/7HO63fvzhd/49//9F8EPjTz/8zp/iI7D84x//xZ9/@M5/0LTiX/zLD9/7wYfv/vDDd7/z4bvf//Ddf6B9@N1/qaZnH3/w4Ud//F//5I/@65/8X/T/Q3r@0X3@H378j//q//2r//@v/iS4fw73vwfTz//qPwAy/80f/wT/P/zjv/mPP8H/v/rnf/PH//ff/Oa/IMPvccN//2f/lj//@jvf@@vv/tO//s7XK57fu/X59T3cv/5f4HL/fN4nnvuU62Ndvv618vM/UxvTVAAH6HMGTAMed@fSYBUWSbN08IBO@KN/9OF3fwNw@3cAEmz/J9jgzy3g9X2yfPnlnF@SZjqk5Jdfgoj4ZSB6fjkL9H3G3inAhqe33gHAl@TLLzaBgkT/H4QCMBZAhWBziRMI7qLkzr/8@p/@DN0nIdH1N2bjS4euM7AxBH4XFvH72JknxZiF/T6Sgw8/@faHn/2DDz/5vQ8/@U0cEaRsKbWdguH89nlUAMzdAw4B8/eBA0AVxUSQ59ciGhjWcPZsLaImX72CRlgDE0hZ65FcBmwRtUZmFc0QEKT/dT5DlcSJOrjHkWwJbGAApzEZwCsJXjtJ/HR1MjKugh@B4jevGRprRXAa40RCFeLFQDxMqlkEAYaNdygWCFlNPmPN9eqYB0yiQ41iYJghdHomqJqQLFYfQoLV8UOGcWHkycgreL@q1orVcQ2je09ZgDiSO5AkQOEntZPj2nuwVylOgI@MH76HrBSryWStCC5VKiqllmpSmmqOCkdlTzIqN7ozhjsZN7cY@1RQiwKf54CqZAE0PpNT6E2av9wE/0ZyPSgO/UMj3esYHtppTPXD3bj/JjpT@AAA4pUk3AAHtyRhbrbAe8yjSlKy8EryGKDmksQ9hVGCA7EpyUiS2jdJFkgf8vAx1wYfoDE6LE4sFgPTRk3ICM1DkBtBQHPPyp6vu7hAR8xjmQn5koDOuJsIN5vFjki8XH@4Dk8V/ntrtDOYSlJZj8TiOE8RZ2FKUjLjZJ0oL0RYQrKtUwGSBMg@BR@8t7bADDVE76lbJDoNx8UNWollaj7LxEiCvs8kYiW1DeSDWOSJ19txxsDqpwQhpeZxhUUMZkdOyhp2mMheOQ3PbznlcvW9mi1E4E32EX4nKvhiETQdfi1b3tjAJqhdSTSFg0ZgFvORWi1YWGZqpHa8dwLgJ4dM1dIyAzHhKlvQsrlsTsvk87mCpmbzpWw@V8wAYcunc5qmlrLZUrFUuKaSbQFtSJXXW7mN2t@7cf0ff2/ZtdwVr0jtSzaWccpauo7UrCrf3BjDBWahkRYqNJdE9Rirp1P40zIZeEIeU2qucLq2Zl1JWOQG7ai7wiV8yGbkSsJJ8E/gYpFPIuwTcIIL0sAlNhZsijg4rAQL4PipR74ILqg5wCMx0gA84rFBk15dXc3ckejaV1/5rFYDbl862I9EoQf0WbjiK5kduS/TBxo7I9cg3x5jDw@@ODg@OHwqPzw4Bub7W3jYRo5Er6@vu5N1CrIa7PDwMIKkB0SqjIrhr9tsNBqRbwvs12M9Mpy9KsOIpklaRsqokprB/x0GDf/3h9fgr@ETQmW0CD/SZeGZlHCCqhR5//79mLYTlA9sP9hXoGWL6M4i2AceAH1/oHJjLj81ptG4ERzor0Vo@bQOGHcawa9/1U8jG8rE8wR1KzyFpgNct9lj3EXsO@zE4btVd4z2CojdPv@O/a7rgHD168Ps6PYZ93po8kPeE69HOmp59Qam318B8Xw4wKNhhvu/LIa9QQsyiAspHGAHHq7lOMsACuz50YpSPpnoZMGdCqSUBcCfHXz26GTmfbK3vfsokmc7h08fLrxyAVCOPd7bP5lYC9w3DJqbRPGtvcePF63BC8hpheTpNZYrpFIwKsED3ym66C3HXoYgqryaXdF9HaT1OsueVvzrTfXBAzWmHD1GCf/IhXq3HAVk@PfSxhdSrVhxjbH/PmmP2PMSEMLaXh@/aOtWd2JdIOU9ow598xTFe6gm4DQsQ448wS2TJZWf/zG9CB3Dw29o4ffy/AieC@/gd7Jx/qWFH6weDdlKR3ihExpds9eHEeTCCQEiLV1ncH/sBeFnRXKosFsdfJ4Gud3wsZaA4zq92WXpiEw0QSsVc8VSRiumiqViNqfmc7mUqqXUQrFQAvqdVotqvpgrqalitpTJwgADvrlSIRIFwmt2FQWGUlUQ4F2GaO02fvZhA7@f4cj9WiTKZ73Y24QuQstO7CMmGBBGwA@QeT7tCl83q4KWxSMbGZVBjDprs@j@/m56f18QdtCCc/K7aUHooCVXTKcLO4JgkM8uDIKaIDg8DHgBmM8t6fTOriCMeASoREYQ@mjZyyOPLwgmWna39/cxnddo0TA8gJ1xH26xQksBwGy0ZDIkJAjCm0l0ALfNE8pSTvfQgmmizz732QU/QfgszE86DTE843A8hkdhWbe3BeGAW7a30edzKniOZ/UbaNmmSxBcsAASCkIPDD3XMGxBaIERUVEQ2mBqX@rghp/YQMUitq8LwiWvIKwiQRgTtN4@E4CZDdwxmUePHul9v2P0@HXp8ncbsgY@5ni0t9/67LNWr9dyL7f3PnuGPp9//kh/fTlyW71WEKzVhMuBMOBzNrhcvCCPB82mbi31@Qb42As@zcumgXlr6m8gT8HVw0QGzc/B53PwGS@5eGxwDQC0hdfOAN47eot8wot86D1utYQKIqp/OTRwrg/7zJkNtCA10NuuU0H7uLoWT8RTl/V8@rRCzmyQEK/SlWv07SboI45IE8Wry/q4mj4FAaegBcdKEkJjrOVMIbU22FRLufKavqlq2eS4jBqCnW6cxSV1M6E@WH@beCpuaplsWWhsbkpCXT3d1NRiOV94uT4SBLGMz81Mofw2kY4DI4oPsV443SzkZkIUCkld0cqFgli5hprwYWBqjXyj2UwkLgz9TBQxr8gVQP6pmOySimhWuolxalzlmWKXYmVcVSv8aDtL34irg7pVRvilNB5jD6Ibb6bLSIoTgloqCpC@oiREEakR0g94v3oRLgJNXjOGOSO/ZFaW@GcW1WJelPGAQtPpNulTU@zVLCQy2ZEXeJqIThKHm/5INPHKkRPkyXEA0Bnqb2rhl13pZDgIiFwfEOPzH2qhFInUArb0iH/kphJYP3u0KwOnGthQS4u8jx/0dlwZP0Trz/lwDSKh0wmMYvIjA7fytUO3XX7GV94bgwiC5xgqV9IL6Xo2xDFw3zwNPOZQoQPteGAY1dWYHaZXa2DSOyxB6TNdvKByNmu1arM6MAZD/xIkI76KDKUKgz8dDdgO47B4@ig8e9Gs7kAFpCs2qmwz0BobR8eRWgcV0uxUd65GZWQqrytGlT5XLkTxxNamXR3Znt41jgwXDwsdHMLYbOCpnHb/VWMPAXehsq@upZrL7GkhDjxeR5OjH5ShK8xQ4NGspq8rs7lO6FKtJVZ61TqCvsPHhiQIp5JUf3cKIlYlUoPeV7mM6lVv1OLf9Eu3QLrKV8bgphaylT5rVVsvxxW3OgShgFUsqMUZWYfpFYJ/Z8FA2pSb1fG0NjLVugbSTjoVyj8a7gRLaelSSlNhJIURFkLCXQB7Fm4VbvBXUTpKWAmBMSGVHqdlNaUaagpEzVdm55WY8p09G1okXS5jw0CjkhXeOhOT2rqV6DhM35CojaGLVyjjeqrPhiY8EhDumaFbFEAUJZaQ3mzmk7m0KFbeQK7dWKIj74ib2UonscOaIjgAbwC3xvLZSreaeCnO17FYSayJVc94Q/WJpIIqY7gGzRFIgN5oUE@ztbyaupKa0rWle35MLWjl@ihWl1Qobfpdb0P4qiacQtNcswj8ZhdwgPWogFtIFjizMmU3pm5DZDktA1pRLWmVACQyDIhUQkjg9575xtNEPF7Q4nExXsF5hzVwD4gcUaQ4kMf4A3VTAHZHKAslDSTLGeJ2IwtcnMqD0Hcd6ZjekIFgFb2KXF9db8zu0/kGu7zUk1JofcBYLxmLMIWW1eVmlK2RSZJrND20Xd3uPdsO94Rt70aiZdo4Nt3lwxrBSV1JWfvYtfzkRu0lfzdw3wqkGiEVRXV2GkiHWgbK3JmxQ/m8qwivVb6dQ9lI1pRGRBCob/PlwGJO5Dll76Ok7Z/tXnUDolR@ggImS@hl3mfrp@L7p6Z1VcxINZIgEyz6Pgk1QruQlPdRGBauqaLDnWbfeKXloOptJ3QAadQH4gejSC4n4BSM8YoNj0svCy@LL588P3x@uM@20uViuTjTEI2tVEqNq/ENtgXMq/lsD@SVd8zJqe/tz/lGvGglWh7GM9l4ZjZYNTquZsNl3oRaq0nqhsY2AUNZGehSV81L6Xc1jm418shr4PPhN36cHW8Uwa4Bg1iGmswltVpNXdfE6PDD1/8Gj3Fd7X2x/ZjF8VD93/7Zz7TC3/7ZP6dVxfh1Bd20TCEKkGhU84Xo1dXw6uoaLu6Xi55GeZ6yBRHMfL1bjdaUwFktqGLUk7gNspuLeu8CLRsJLV0Ev91DbhPyUIvRUjQSLT559Y6xDRAka51ez9TIpChzwlmsDIIX/Nl7nLh6L629AqrieTEFtz@WEDicbVmv1WrrtCsyXkvicUQtR1P@9evKKZ8NQWlk3aaf4a3jz3g5cVj3PLCHNrCubxgsV1MZiC@K8uE3flfT8n/7Z7/dEN813zW/CXS2VCrlVS36q5tXNNCgpEFeDJtvjS3jwV6pyPf4I/l@7fHPsYfnG@lT3MAnk04cj77napn2GQRAzgDM@JFXYCXK7J6HKSPBwP0WT/cE5pbuGflsaPMuPdyXjvOEeLjRKytKz/T7oxadZjxxLw/8QzrroQD@mCD1k7llOS1loONsA33ZywNRCiBQEfzIVmC0xKMa9OVT5F5RbUWTlFRB0TpNAGtisRJiOcIg5SEevW6Mu12BzmwbVufYGOqkjAj8w4OtBx0EQ1VVdCI8PIw8x1lNTiJTjRssvss35Et0pNwhhsaLh4cQqWoZqbsw8IiIgIeig6NNtNdekNGGH7MWwn32ANF1UFttCE/fu54GmHz@ehoCy4gaWQL@oTpbIpak8ifDTOC8MnegfEytQaJTB0qIcuMyM6W7PVLDZqMiK0grAc0qo1bOulo@TXGOs6pSfdPZdxMV@gAbjxpeqCRYoaSbtGu6wLSpxRndL8SyUcjZciSrQU4AkDcInvVGHWR4csFpvSZVR4EaCsQ/OfQLjv@jojNSOgSIbwf6eNlFy/QJAAY4AsCQSg/PBPEqSs2hamvUw8MW2Bdkx@0ppueNjFyhmKUM6XiCOwQFJncOVFMCJeEKZQ4PTE9KUfL7zDLODYtUEgTZRm1UOu@UhGe4twYVUCKrnhcJdaAq50oKtZAopbjbw739x9snew9TTFJzCI4n3trOBDYxU7ncO0n@XWvk9QM0wiC8@8qtfJYjecJLxbeUuBhkfWu22pOzGQ4jwG954dTgMBGvUjDXGOCH03jEbKh3kFalKIwdD07143F6fmrM9DArI9dCvAkrN@z50aiAKI1pRREFPb8DoYKv0kMYLFjA4YANCM8NoJW0AmogoG5NHzASdZYQ5grLjr8DYZWkGlfKIOxa@CXFOOrXmqW2ceo7OoufoBZ3GOKJtK3FiS6g2od@Nf6pF6@0gXkPOQt2nhiJV0EJTLuLuUjwijtxdi7D9kuMgvM4AlSICOyxODmg84s/jwO3MYnPsxK@eHWuu@xtFTCUepzMifqeReceE3Gu3BeCvZWRBwnOwVX9yiRAy@lcyqi70O7s9k2rk3g7m8YQGE6zm0gm29VqRryCJN0hECdvCMTQQJFOrKBbd84NLKQ9J6E0GjbkT163jQv25ZPHj6DJnxl0zL3@8nQ9pqSAwRUrWAS9mkCgh4dPjnTXM1xRHuJ7fyI8JfDbJ0EiMrT2wKunTyn3KQGLpmAvBMrZM/yg9N7O5Ynee6oPjERcj/MDZpiUCY1ibugyl5IqZjIpQhH1unk6V0dVYb5xBfGqVyWovmt0Ky2o6LPKtVc9T/TEig@v/mwSOUiiqmkUuw@Bqh48FmrdxC@hPzp58rga39AZxlpd0iviydYEOQBRCGHo5Py26@qXc6gDVIWwyudnRAlh4ErGhdp8WTYUvRYHxnVlfh47pNlCluX4FIE7iVEqwDi3erNJK@4UCy6HRhUd@ND22d6JkIKw7sgQ0dHG4e2SiBZXf1AN0@DohpSChsDLY4SpVrMPHpAbV31SrWrptAioWbmG2DzA3MRE@HEr165e7SQmFakPzSWqFjRZU3Tbu0CF5sACp3OFTceFIaLaAR7ygQckpIpKu89N//KBB9hWDdU2PODnT6tr2fXiobnzzS9Lx/mHiXbrc1VICa89xwZBzR3OZsDVL2TOFgGNddscuygTqNy0rStD/cxRsp10u5guqoWOUcgZxXSm2M4ZmVILuMR2N1tsdUoFvZBrtxQY3HwKIg9M/NaWwNEfk@3eL9lVjFkRBP9uVwXuvZMrdUtaOpPJtoq5Tjqb7RZVPZPJd7Riq9S6nWub5geFrpDu4tixSIE/Xc3cRW7Q9iC0@D8A';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,R@'_  7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:_a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& 1111111 \#184O@     11 @O252<               /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D//> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@" ;   L      ;       xo--o+++o+\;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>> >>">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]x<  >>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_       #v
#- ! ++R++  +++++++++\+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._     #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@//:@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];t}?1&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rext~+nu U9583>Ehar Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2]putsngt=>+le.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8           \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3           \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Yet another language from [A Brief History of 2D Programming Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829).

I used Java interpreter downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/brainspace/downloads) (dist.zip).
Command line (Windows): `java -jar BS1-CLI.jar polyglot < nul`.
`< nul` is needed because `1` in `#16` is input.

BrainSpace executes the same code as Surface, and then is redirected down with `\`:
`> ++++++::@\`.
BrainSpace uses Surface's and MarioLANG's pluses, like Minimal2D.
The final bit of code is on line 4: `xo--o+++o+\`.

Answer (score 4):

## 256. [ETA](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/doc/), 11888 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@Nadhj6@TD3H@TLFsjTBEQCIMCH@BCpltTSaZ3pbmlaOqfPHFLNBkmQRAsE2AAoUa1W18wkNdcTu3KdyVzXeHzjMzOJc@2bVMVJJdeTil2u8nxNufLJP6CdL7dctzz/YLLW2gBfIiWdiV0VkAD2Y@332muvtR8LLcPv/@pXcbzYkWtf9mw3YIHpB6zjWeemp7CdS/bQsPy8no3FEGrb640GphP45VicaYw55gU7cNpWB9xY4J6ZjvXW9MBPZ2zouT3PGLCgbwRgsSAUe2Ta7wbvAtZ2BwPD6fgAmWXsyADP7qh9xoyWH3hGO7BcB7xyjH3m2Mag1TEYQJje0DMDij7PIIr2GYWZ9ykw9tT1fBOTb5u@76LjBmOb5mAYXNbAUgQIw7PcJ9vPPlkIXGLsEwNyNrTN8UJetAx7YZleZyGEprHPT/b3F1119g3Zddj@zfxpWfaZ5xu2sRh/jm2PAvcgWHTPs@2e6RhMV0qKvuhZYDuecSPIBvNMo9O1bFOxnDaTWd@0h6bH0IV1XQ@aLDDtYqaYaW5PQyptDFucei5EW40uZng9HzzdcxOMJrTE0DI7rOu5A2Y4/gWkpJUyU3iMtjSPDm3IICAae@1D6I7JfMcaDs2Ae0JxTY@8IWVmW85ZjGPfked2Rm3L6QGcCfU6HAVUJj/WhmA1NgxxWEEDi1MtcDDIwrE7MGfbwgfkhVz7Q7Ntda02rxxzHJiOD@X1FWZB211Yts06pg0BprG308x32cifcWrZRl9pKzGsXEyFDc5sZrH2cMi4FxQDsrSfKTJz4L622Fvwt/s@Gw8HzLcG4B203W7XNNlbc9iH4GzQiXXcGIOrPVwo2cSWMAHGMaF0u0ffgnoLsDqdLmStw1ozcJAPyjOV2HBcqD6POcaAY0N7eEmlh2gmIbquq6B7xzV9JxmwC9c7Yy2zbWCxMTHf7HWNkQ0pWl1sDsADy2cDF97QiA6DbEHgAOsC48bEYksLgslEzWsOoWNi87qILtDWUStfeAbgh@eH7RhYA8AOK0j6zDR8CykWBPFNp0OYMZzQMhdKO9vo7NyCjgdVMfIobt/0CPUpXoalgCiNCa6KF54VAEZgKbbZkWl47MQzTYnjqem3jSFi6WySkJiLKQRYEIUQc3MzuXe4nwQE5SEUYwgI6WVPvvlpzGBKlSWaFbirglCJ7T17xK4SDTRzmglIPPREQ2LV98xXGw0T7rHWUnvedQxijUGt2Ex1h4FqyEPIoBxABlUDjWiSz3VlaM8kzDYX2mCm23CoDrQGEAH2eZpK1h55HlL3aaUaZ1Bo23V6UJ9QWG/k8CYvZKAJAP86fpqZ5ybiAG8j94Jq@KQPGAJ/AJ2hLHzAoQqFIQe6YlijUbq@a48IDkL6AfZHqBUIijEedNnnrGtYNgYBf4yK59ozfUBODDNyOtjyA8sxOwqLskFUx4O@eA7JGRApOUBvGMzQFsoUAENDuFRU9Prw27/X6fUgnu122/U6Ibp@DsjepqHRoMzC4MYQYV3HsClbAJfG1HlwSODcsK0OUTnDuQyToExQqhfuyO4w6qgXFnS5vgHE1gQC0Q5MjuTuKIA8ptnAOOMU0eKYCwUfGC1oWEqA0qZiy@zhLrRSG7o54Yw8GAXdIpOHeyzpqy/FrbK4tdYwIXOSIq0nVLVXAYRT1skJbMnbMOfz7bmhwg8M37U6seFl0HcdncltJrSr7tB0xORcHMl00mslJQUptShVrGpb6VpOR0xuAi7WIOGkVGlX23WrfFpZCD6bJERzgdFgdzXFtiQgqaFOca4OgLlQgJJ9LoemGT/Xb2KVo7cy44wVs@h2zh3ixLogXrqIIECHFN82zaGYUTQJyQTCLS03eiwr6UIcYYHL1mkqGU@mZotOMUBJ5wqKnfXEcpFs2cM@8htQKY4/BJrrIe62DcAeHwe1AFi6NGsRXtNICJSFaOKFmQSq3QJCGuERdUne5TC8jIQyjGHaheZ7stmZ6chABKAvB/4Namy7yB1QnnDkAdLhYKJGD5oGAvOCbPOC8JTIZb5IZw4QFIytZbKi3LKgE2B3A5oe4vxM2QA8q3MYiI13khnaMzAucVTjrMG0w@CYZrABkAfvkrVNpDlAfEw@oGAiI@p/PvC9zO2yjKzn8/N97EYXCzx1W/4SiPRb9daehIWf7UxIaFgX2GzbcHojowf0wnUgiNFum8MgJFRQEj8AUrQ43pCjHA6eit@PJR4upk2DSMQeTdNAIs9bLxwKDaQuIdsuA0@GrB@XBVjH8oAswUi@kDoAnC8kLrxCkLkMvBJWZCHiAADJzLHZHgVA1QCBL/pWuw84i7lzOF3kg9Bi8uA0mzpQdrk7SRozo9Ue6DFFnThhNlZGIWOL3owHBleMqjbnQI0/63B7zIY/WBKxO8kiDAQzropqKIB7d8Q5cB13SaRQkZNoEWTeh7cDcGLHyBTDwBWxXdRZJ5zypImgzYBqQM8H/OsHwdAvwzhhBf1RSwFMUU@8y4Pg0EFkUQPv0gpcbm7ZbgvIsg/9U41SUNujljVeKBC5TdrwtR87Bwas67MqjNxvRoB1YrLrA8Ek910EnvESiHBTFPwpACABKVBRYtcnUrwPROX40mmLwhxSCmkmYN8VJDBgwEnVfIrM23w2X4PTYi4RbDYziopQqu@1ySDP8KQYPYJTtmIfzRXtnnmMfSQI8Ogatm/C2xnZNlpHDqdyIucVJHYV@@gjIG0iJWcNhrbVtoIm92UPHoQ8BVsDGQ/Zpi7yTBKE@SgUphUgKAATDj8cWgncY2J2RQkK8tH1XMKm57keTzfoe@4FIwcEi81W6q47QOrOXhDDhRw0iLWWg@J9OJbSUGosZSEmYyrxy8mk8tq1HPEquba2liwnazBirq1tgWkTTVtoSoFpi0wymRBOQROFSJMJfesUAt1Ok9f1KOaxdIrdYYyj/VtrKBr1cjl7mjbqWvjW8S1BPcOIAdAyviCepFStolGShNoFFFRpdedLv4uj3nHbs4ZhJXxqnBvcHtZClqoBGs71UDCoIPNye50Mqh5wFyAMtPuil2zUM43TxlWjk2pcJ9MYWqoY1RYUCtITB0rPc0fAhkj1XFnWTiWpngXmo1VNZpLroliUQYwDSUT6uCilDF7bYtKE0VBsNJJQqWH91Nt9j@Ibp3VJmlQV5AMZHuC1xaRyVYT0W9KplEpCWCmZBtGtmkxCzbSxEnwqNPaluQo6fP4NXjG7qVSMujdIpXjfGE7BDYXe@eBHo7dvkXbxOFoTDLNHBufyhiGAeuBEsAp6LgitkVery5COzqXxidvlUtEuPvae7MfMMbXWJ4f7e8@rlEzf8M@Ap5B7CKsCrwy14nUUoAb2qGPGlsEA2QBTe5oTnDvAxHvtNpNdRmBym2diZrhosxWxAa0hxtNlsj2YL4Lfh/zuzpWBIiF3Cnkb/9KOssTBl@ZpkuQ@UOzd4ydzU2SDM@AnWNu3kfmWPV4AsKrr3LFDr4mMUWYHJKM5wGACbgF/2ZnMBTiuIyMtjMQ5dzYhPiECEOSG3BZyEtYcDEbctcYgEsdxPiVk/ZFjRe5/13VAODWVF0QNBQaEHGerTGUp/3/EGSml7U97J3D6YBzaRhvo/Xx0DYE1IEKgQKq63Eeq3Ih4UTggOf6uMgIr1TYcrL@ORXLqyPL7WL0gS@Ao4HWhVlFIxckdqrUD1gYutwc1bY6tgEut0MOPMchjwxcllJO2uZyBWIY8MmYqmrkjBtZtg4RvAq@Mvny6hO0555bnOljJyh5EDaSogm2wEPmy6gU02t4@0B@trt9lkUON3XDWZup2NtbFym370Lsc13Z7LlsHAERNReGIfeDgDCdIOYExhB5lvaUK2u65IOrP46BpTuZMC9mJvGkgpErwymsYBdjyQk8BVpT5@ODLPWBDtHwmA/mPbBm6JoWciWWxjOjYZlOAcBXARrzBlvzSHPYvvTl08t1w3iSgyUPqmHwmywAWEnIV9vC3FHS2k3MX6OeRVycyLSv7HskEOHk3K1fPlX6OW@HdBkoYX3BG16gq5iK90eDT9kXC1VDn6NZkqkDuDtzAUD9XgETjI4YcsmwxwVeTa0lVlvEpkBfTa0ztmOcqUqlpzOM9s7007rFptlX0xcGNRYal1RN5rqiaBlwOPaCY/B3VwSTkYvl7qRQSdsrdJG2eaRjkT/ojM2a2@y4TGiBizJZMgAGiD7KyDDUPDCDKJZNg4YpQLHBHINZ1TNsaWMEBzdnbDsouChFvBalW6LsL9GYawZFlAkPOJxymgwzOq0/HKKfH4Z8DJadYQcRXeJV6Zkddn8b21HU9kCt9ptGcgj6p@kHoobr@sKMEY4iAh9qj8d2Pxvlnh4/2mkfbJ4@r6sj3VNtqAY3omM0BCLM2dIcVF@YNZwj3AHcsxx1YUKIoyrdn9nPXDTjzgAsH97viGDCK48mj5pODnefbz78VZo5GdGswsg3MYzmxADCJ45hgbo2m7bZc4C2c0cqYgLk43Dl8EsXy6WdPDrabj/aODk9monk9si1DG6vDs96qAn2KIExTMrzqD@3O/IoOialzswghsUGZq8JANmWyDE8Z3XiiKJUp6IEsMg6PsoyzwAbOc3tM1zKlUqdlFItmodPO5Ta6RrfTyelaMd8t5vV8Bh4bhZLJ3hG4LJtjmrkBE58VwQkkTAMyTy9NyUUcDoiibeBYLpfma@J7S@ba@by5kSsZpXapVDL0jU7W0IsbplnY6OYyGbOgZbqtolbM3pq5mWwgazW1DWgGCHodThaQJxA/EV5z3YFnHni9C9bRdb3QzndLWb2Tz@Q6rVImX@y0tA2jVTIz3VxW07VOW9fKUVicUQUq0YcGQ67SAdY08pI18JRi0WA628S0yhgtQ4cEJ5FFEjOMlpFRcAg9cugxCheRcWo2dM@je7SEjFM0oXsB3Qe4gDzlZMk6cQwBiwSI68iK14ocS@g4WUGeW1sFUhnSz2X@qwOFMV9pmWuM/ALXoGfKd6Vp5H4edLtzzjo5n8k4lNlT5yw58xXo@bXfsLA3vJYCT@LLUXx85XppfDe8lgJP4svz@HDFe3l0Cz7LQCeRFSgyXCFfGteCxxLASUwbFNPsqvrUr0h@q5bUw7SWeq8MNIm7RHHz1fLma75a0QwXyxGbeQc5AU7siQv88xML5@27cz0mNpHAGzEhmkaYn0ia@ujTZRImny9f3xFmI@LEwHLOXBKcJ6ZmRtHyGMskisGZfTNkF0QNesyB3sjUTR8@fg1aXXosAcBBd3Fmjjxo2jMc@mGoNdTn9MIJ0GU5mJ/KnUu@ZXZHIAWpLctB8x1gcqlIkN1Wy1oFCjWBmw@i9xKwMns@AklUV3KKFom9uHQCNJvPw54cHBJgyyAhbn7@n81VfjDyAggVvv/rtzvQCDebqG9ckiw4MTQd84Lwo7uyxcKgaKHH8tadjvpUMWS6K8q2gUuuhj0xLI@aWl@W@4Y3QJErbG5AUHwAJtyCazznfC4mei9PpMyokufXGZhjDVh7CTTBLiyJ8MRIyLZdo0PVwEVhy6RAHjY2bwZzzIXCGYYHRp5VCS1ZuWDTrQJBfxSM@BN3B9zVjNYQ79u6aAiZyRstzQQW2WhZ5i2N7hlno44rA6dHRcaMFZbATktPk3Vy1zbOuLGJxuXF5wX0rF4P@InwvQrsog@yDQml6gW97sIL3xn5Q7kFjRVAxyEbdYXBLSl4Nn@uArHC/XMTw@pas2x63KPRJ8hF6AIsHVU0bmmSZyrNWqhm22hdoqje//pYhgkSgwM0p9pOpTJZHPYma7@zW5FWh8exksKXSstD881UvEqWiVcq30Ql8wlkKnO4reqOhoWByxoYtqx3ZowrKXo0dTw1LQGleRu5bRs@oFYQNod5Ds1Hj9vQHUemNohd3tR0C7JPsxNtAVi1mhySrbBXt13b8rFr26so6OIC3DRN3M5Gj5kpaWtZxXaIZ/L78sS0nC647QCXclcg2j2oHF9FxXXqGcxR3FWV1nYv8F7JWvTdc5M/lw90b5fm6h4US7YJJaz20hGl074LU3E7ED2W1@PZ0nwFbXup@3wfiKY4ZgW0e@K1b9muz47peVu19DwIxp/LMXq2Bi3DkWk9aNa8PFiYqSFTwlnWFe1q2D3XLhR7qgGPlY0/8ro4JoTv@1K/CfXStLupV8QfuY4WvleS/TPVO7ur7WhpwsNF@xnjLSPwMhIWLkquLiBIErgTZ3nh9jNFCqmoXF5e1QBeu39hXEbvX2NkWVW70cgyvCR@G9g/DFAqgiHwOA/@66SWuz21zv3I041oN@4qxEzjntkmDGT0vNGkTM9oXzOElsncn1h17ZE5MpfSqsPWaxP3t98ihdw/U5mwGIlwthNnhHCucwL1NpQf75VrHMPRdiuBMWwLOvmdnM5SejcEHn2IIvcRGI7QcDNgzxkN5xp3Topznt9ec/1h1LPdzlwm0efrUqTi3fzUHCPvm3TfKlxxYRDXtqrZTCYT8jcz89dzltuEruwk7GuLP@cSJpdpylNYnA3xZozL05hOpULTW2e@jJOa96NO@qoZAQIulVTHcszgEp@rmmQZtW25rv11mhCIbsdC/g24Ulz4uaspb/BG4W4wNp378HHmpNVdNevBB6RQOoXaQ8H7NmyYnXq9VzPLuGQNvbS3YL19HmhmIveuVGCYp8klvnXCXs14hjMqmlJUNm7tkZyddVumbfDXuJC7Lb6Skr01vgnLEvLJtLaF62F8BWy6ohpfoFvDS6gsqwNCTt8cmGS9RTowOq9HfvRaCTR28V7irdB646pwQwsIhYPPudW2GVYqcB0QywLD65ko19i4Kh66riLO0az60so9GBg9k5@ruo16Tqc6cOswlwanxuWTHmW@66wNwfjWj9tRATrTmXnpR@@lET69bEN7jgZ3T9Ut9Ps2bVS6q6Mr6tLFhDt4Rafv9p2@2ec7gSa2Vd0DMDLgJ@JuKwTkv9dvM6JPs7uUZmvWdm37PjWL9JFTS9ftLs3THp7T6kDQrxXvpdECj/B15xQgjPVUQTTor@o3fXMEQ5bvBu7QlMm2CtTGySL@XEVFo8WdX3cW6tYZAqiR6P3rxn@nbNoz3GA4pFdzaI98elBQmY7XLWvKfUrmPlhhBXzbEcdbs@e22n3rriy1TCNwrDM1mhHi1lsl2@FMLVhMfoTOim1B5XmXCmJDddb/GF8Hq5o0nFziw9bEsLyNy2x35HmXWBOB6zLfdi@m9GF@/8RkGpevPqBhVQ7ClcEl3sQN4M66aAfZLUsg4ULiSgQjJhwZbtnMAMOirZxRmtveOdM7sln@WMUXLZSfMjWzfvt1pkTDbQ80OWjNzNyC@xz@zC1GLx2snP6o598kd3zCvgMsFj6WtvR2D880LzQ0b1QYgQwnfK2qb91Wcfs2vJvQciPz1tWV/K3LKwSn2bLhWvBqwgvacLRy2sy2hj5/MrmrL2UYbi4h34S6XC42h@3TMbt8LQRNd3F6A9fDQ0TAUshtz/TbOJWOFJnzT5z6OG4PKLNssylwBLu0CDdXrZc2/2TEk794ZvYM3F75xMKdlvYSrIBYFxev74r0myPDt745cgNzaXyLC9h3RffU6Fntx3M1H0UW1Wi4B4@/5tAenW5W/kXf8un8RmS4Zc4JkYyjLeJZE/j9ZdLawnT95GD07dMqM4xSuPebyQcs2iM@MeCCAfobS9NaNhPvDkluvCTTbZPwVkAzs@F7KVYt3wRwW/IXo8Fw5Iev5anTPp3ZKerBGbn7FxaQRfkNUGPWN@xg@TT2zMws8FzhIDk1ruLCv7Rst8e@LGYYsGgwaCNTvgThdmC4PjIC6BHOEgSmtO@5UIqTHrLHC/YGcMLMMtlyrOD2CZ4gMEBGit5YGD7Y4ClE9Qk@lYdfNwb5ZHmNPLmVg4Gx/bJt46H4rysJcLILWHhMh9bRODk3P4v3YTLmbhhhNLo45sWsvHbrok8Zh1TXGQUy7vK/bUwp3DqmlNm4WJhBDSZ@c@/pZ9IshtD217v4UBMEwZFvX05NKzceLCCe5QCztpoWz0NH0sQjk1QaPKeNmneE2R7i6Ski@Y/cZRLP0SWMPvcWmWAAGQ0emW1cebwz7WfuU2DdYCgbAtEdPDdxy8ACLVkeEIM9cduGDfXTuTOZY4p2yVgxFa6NodmC9rWnpuW82LKIHxmBsYJ3oolDkgAnpjtxxbJbpveaZgRnzKuE2vkMPTbHJIasRhjeC@Wg3eYMN07LzfWRxbUdf@i6Dn8SEc7AS3t6O7GB4YEe919xV3D/8tzot1RImy/t4TnfbmJ2@MG9VcX1zJZr8ycWYQU5cCy@ucDwLNNXn1jOaExuTAbebbmYw7fxZpQNnObw@9DZLiyQsSe7e3GzGt8q7C9IUsASnxs@Lfkvl2nmdhLff1dR3/DaLq6dhYavuXI2cyTsDjo@2SrNtya0oFHGQNCM9ijSK3BHVu1Ba0CPlTLJTEs/N1t45K5F50cDY7yMiZw/OhY6LhzeikgadvwCE49A6pHuHsgWRbb5GreG9CCCfrEUTaLknllm@60h3UFLJ72I5pJVgyTapR1pfhMcsDm2KQd93GOpBsEqgvHMOht17rHWFS2gjAYmrlnPr9ysRCrX7xNGuMtX6ScE1zPDrdu4SxC6fmRGqitvr0RZjB7@hzufqjAwNws5PME/Gss9IGd37wuAzI88J3zdB@2OXD/oWuPDIapxcr1V9AWLlYcg8OLdAU3rqwoB7emMbD7f0ZvZ0TXokHwH3GDXBZNNJDwwZdM5l0nF0TharvSMSI/MyjZc3Byq3bE79MKfrAeChzz06a0O/aODJ4cnytDXbpk5xA1/I8vG1T3KSuQGBSTT6inqY9qrdju/@ehwZ@/JNhM7QGRcR7oDOlwQHfaNlhkYqrFSzkFfM1hCUcMTNqQMaKI2wk@HZ7/AzfLC8@W@Emm2Cg/KEd2LjmyAo9Fuj3CKBnBHYQQoikYqJUmxMNRj94INUG0OBvLpvOeZNaywTGTEovZhaCN4PPEusoTBNqtM1zNMkipceQTUCzTuyKywrhVFve37Vs@BLEQ5IL0/qBOEqxTyGfDPQRRvvc4SV@NypqxdsyoTygI7PeU5xosS2RsPSWnPcx68njBOq4mkLCcTyYZTZpnkBNy0QW5cCm7MwUJm8RVmeFK/XKGXS9q4JrVZ4TpPgJ6jPqG@4XRsk33m0HoplN/jmju4WpgT3Af8iz/shGqWSJ3YwPINGyoENaW5A7PvXmzxdKPqGg4NVNOEcVz0cY4XU5d3txnIn0G7z7UrQXN9tn9SDHW2hGrZwHLEZ/EmueCYg0uJeP404IjBczM5SxgmPAkVFQoEm9HAAU6iE/R9hR1bdLR05E0Pi4TK6pzAw/WCTpodsI6JWy7pxDAtj9mue0aniDAnv/hDrqmGzg2H5zmj5ElD1UyKeDxYI/Uw7bY7glxHkbw1PTcEEbGSQegf4WI0KUgjdwlP05IKHcB2OVIgQ8lwLTK728dM3mNJVL2GCh8qVldMbD//5PN65rT6ng1U879@W5WuwooTPpZLBV9Iswikco2INeudB@@pb5IJibHAE5wcqrZC0eWCtweqjeNIhueqIxxz3WHUbZAXJp1XE2wMdUmIaKZ2jjTJDEh/GCGseUGaZOj0noPEmfTX@dDBwCpR1LzXVRPiiK@PyscBy0OCqI3HABPXOEbHjFErCgZJjNk7RgQUmGEtnwEbr0gbFfEMqjvRhvzs7EEJ9ZHZGtFm4XNd0fNVKk6iWd2skQkGWxcVYtVfNsZ6Rm6MN/ZOgb0PK7XRGH@c0b@AWnc9CPVAxZ639@zRVUKpZd69841LJgjXyQo/2AFkInF1dHC0d3yyffLZMbTCdUTa9vnxrojWIBbRic2@a5OqMagX5LO/Bv2Z2KZkEJVZSlJs9mwdgYZ1LchCghtnSNNc6DuCLwvvmzP@NwFCmta1WGwyMgAWGIRsWGtY@NEQFaaxMGyo9ImwzMLxAzvQpGLw@MwSWkpVJbAqVJYMlXXPqmKrC7vF3e5TY3fGcnu1bS0FwRqbpFef@PMiLq2C67@Tcg8N3/@fLzeP5fZyE8wt5QbQiWsUZn/74Mlnz/fmg0WDPFHdaikfHirlxBl7GufVIy1XpMshDIjry1WBCRSAW8PBjOvaNIMLE4oVEsf2gAcmDKX8C7EpYkLNVFHd62nIhYgi5QD5G2REFs@8AiM9k8VojJ6J7ooXcUIE9oVJ1FHGFSGMOU5qSxW8omJgrGF1RV3viIh4SK@T/iz7k456HBYNx@iRz/vciqFqMur4DP4zo1Jk0k/ZmIXDmXbKZKbDbZtODwocwUoVPkaxBK8IIcHzLkzyi@omIU@d1wYt6dBZjvCsKIzStjH0I2Ywzp65gVlmb0Yu6aOIiMmEvyBNpwbXDktNy3Wekp4LkKGBf47GLYrvYP@4itwZZ82Ivs/i3MjBgQqAuKLW8MR44KFCY36Ul2tM5FXuhsr5oqGSpkX8UBnXhEvw2bnlWyDUUyN0kcexgVJiacKCo7Jf0kTCtm0feJIODN/AoQQ41AJzotABQ37KUHaYEAecVCYsY5oJMYT1qzeVtcFQeoFi3iseOEFwFLM/E2dyc02WoeZ6lhNp9i2jql@aESizwBvh/sFa8kaQKAtlMsn9YGDPAC5RW9kw1Q@//XtcVWUjAPP3Q/M4swO23wxtXTD/VuSjaWD7ZxObDrYfcNtLFZvspn6@aT4nqhZWHskE5Hwo3CgYEoZIxzEVaNLk2NyfHxwxv42qc7FBB8Z4pq2QzERyCrMGgBnn1NAIzlOYtuM0HrH@OeAJIBcgCfI4yNZQeqZ3KqKqtrKqYsZxpUehjZzmmG@uIM1tb0aosRQ4MbWQL@Q0FTIpn0cRkjKZHp4r4xFKUhkIY@zcGlZftdpsc3OTCX7bsM1qocIRRE0YL7PCq0lGEwAb49JCnUEYCDINAX61MJiYMFKahEFxNEtqSSRsHZfjG7CEIhkAREJnJ1I/ATynG1YVILNjjgNimy4jKQiotuPOqCqOIpIhIh436tVc7JPTs2I4PTnTS5XZZhBeIBjJ52VhGcbWX7JG0HBOQ/2qDLDvJ0vw1wHzP1midJVjFqrXuantU1zU1YmlYQ@PHRdnefcht0zUVT2ragVpBkOFMCrIL/b3dxAl9HCgGG3Teu0O/e3dvYNPD4@Ob2h9IsjkIliSJWubqYaspOunE0Nyku/5St3ZV4@f7uxHVTmbq@k8K0JMN84uZnNZaos5XZH6C34s72ba5HEjIS1z34hpkkbepw3oN2Of@qozgLv8VNCNVEXp6rp@ullrOPEbyb9bpsk3rqwjcoGp4ZMe3@RiNjGLE639J6i131eiM@caHjjHk4iBezY9vh46zHhw8CgWoAAxRY2gVhFPyMAhnwGa6lnR@WcDfCJ9fJaI9KtOcjQDeRJ9YAC71lQtYKgPr2/4fdtqxWAA76COSK7NJlLXMtGDo/hD2wpEKUZTIFVkg4CIieFnBsblsULLwyJp86W40uw2FXtRfFIMOgHElzwa@X125A5n5rYemZHpOXAj7NGIrx2a7NPRAOC69HpuIok1gT@RITBUVHKSVS5VQ88KNeyNU6jFENKro569sODKoJMXx5LSN8cdqwcEXJTS0NM/1oCtmugAwEKT1j0nCTSO1/AneBprtkq/lqLF8TRyo24oltMxxyJqDiqfAn@K7smLF@dJSbiBA6TtcTfSD7eg9jHqiEYQ9oipysSFzlaafFtgQS9nqYTal1CdATQLpHgceE/ACOOT2B0YQyaOSB@pzxRGVrEhOmk/8CQm17hKE4elUiRVw4s8gGtG0C6ZCHGYiPOQolqF1kFX3@ng6601ZHVNUU7BTIlILIEzarswlONclBQDKQmClCnaKrYtK2OOOPYqHPMgDPrHSEEaQ6WcS7xJjSbNvrtYF1RqVnswo1hq2gN5rZZK5bA15klNiQFa3KTyigrRLiEhEZcK9RueTodaQzXz@D0CXJwAsvDwG6bjmFBBgDMDA8ZgYwRI5knp6Lsi6alackohzrP4ODzuDhmdV1e@l7yycQU7oVZocqZyDWPqqwYOqt1wWL1U/6GqqJUrMWFXL1VgdKSamOhXtVR2PZVKOOtiwsGh/sEDnNO5TgAn0VRARBoDkJywpQrgM3Ae1YRTSRibYqJT1dcpBFhBSLuCAO99VblKGNdq4gGM1Glw8XjnFRM@abzMKIp2DfnDHpJQ04AzV6ggkD4qgsknrFQK86AkmpiB92rjOEU0u3Gs0vRRJeRG1d4g7G4LVHXSEjc@qcIrMHQOGxoIu46EPTxl0IyAp8rKs8v8VvAePOFv4EEuRntHTX@W/Rfmfe5PWEJ6lyRlZFy/KFc5ChU4FqES0Zo2JAmIya9@FdcKTBATW4WsfZ5K5jMVeGiVDZZnHycaei7O4g@3t09AZFfXrxqPir1zZnb1whtZrltd5c3p0dnR0RfjS6khJuO7hy8FLQegG6xE932vDaavuNjXu@LxdTUWV9e1Bxuq@urVK2B58arXlFoEopxKdTl5Whc3QodBbWNjPV0orqefP0w2IS@GEUiirkvHzLJU1rCGfqcDt9unT/yIcX6xrS1MDwzwZ6HbYNwl43jb7PVGe8Yld7fiI3ztB2HYp1@@ePECDS/oYm@fh@HjPMYwuni5aeTjlEk9o//i52vX6auj5uYvvjNQzTV8HeLr@9dP0Xys5T9eW/t4ZyeXS0PFcfPRl0ff2t7ezj1K54/q@a2cnFnb/Is/W1vT9U1dXTv1fe00WT/7QtAzOUH5xc@SzaOjb/o@th1eWaaBEZ9FuDWWz7Mz9hausy7DP5nfdmbMBppb3bc4QAKzXCVik0zms8njl0lsn7dxTdPil/RrUtHWmFbb2vhvPzx8Ew/iNV194cE7iL@JF4pxbgQD2LKR7Txei28iWOE6fqlWq1Uwbvy3fwfha59CPOhzuQmPWj6Kq3AZr8lVCvIuXiuAQdN1SPf/@/a3Y/HaGDJRqx3sM72mr4doohUfaA/I5AR9YDAaca2YO3xIVst8eKjn9U00OyZ@GqUP4igSGU3TGyxsPC1sQiyuhk/uwPpgxjZ14ywCnbY5izCKhZgACEI4ws2hA6ENd0DvObgXDcNY30jl9IdO5cXMNWf5@7ie4zeoCmsPXz1S1c0ajPR4lcsPG82wm6lsoyi47kOc/KuwJ6FrBR9jV5ZdAIe7QY4yXmEFxovVdJNXUtTLIh82tbFZp3hYl2zSoX4NuD28/vI//uWP/vKH9PsR3f8lFo92mMj189NadAEGCTVPuGqEVucpe8ovx4E/3JEVXdABTE44NxmfXLUaPugf2shE7wW30Kc2sRDENMhKOBZRLEo3Fn@vqqyMrXReq82WBy51YqVi8JyT4elM6ablC8sDpHFraw1@9IdrYsXnGrmEzgRy81pjtVuu28eAWLwer5@e8m69WKJbrucKYp0S2pqzo8p5LC4DoUqlngOWshC54Wqk7rg@g1tRmqFNVaaxxmPxv/OrFmPxK7hOU/L1dT2Zc5MF96HyMlWphH/g8yoTG17cBDk8vZblzZe1VKpOOa3Xwixvyuy0xgtAT6X5chOiT23WN6vuLt1KE@tLPn1Zq2/OB6bwp7WHD1NYtQ8hglrilIFoAa1xvXldu65vXl9vbsJ/k57X4Rtcrzdv/Ok1vVbATP1Psf0bdbXWUMNeWTsFuwJIDS6K2kDshjfA1eux@BViDqufkuK2qlzXCvlTmVEPWQfqpZa1dT2r5scfF/Z0IAI@guuCoK6j4R0Ol8DwlGJxFB1KXIIokcOrD1/9P3g3Pnz1b8AKWcMv5JFv6w3@nrzF35sAfydt/D1/g7@Tt/h7HuDvyMff0xb@YvEqY8CxJbYyduY8o51pZ2CwWAYY5n6mr3VgsGEZk2UuM5csM3C1DphM@GXAZGW6LNNjGSfjaBp4giFgmQBNXXj14NeFWDz4WZkMRp45Z5CKjUMYKTym97smkxqxOku@MoHNUjQloxSs5mm@MHxTT55W4mqjoXLek@m5Cim4vr5mrNnce/ao2VQR@RtP3cPp//BwMGu99T84dJ8eugMX/oeHh08bQMBqqYcp@SFc1VpqM3xtxWuVrUZZRsSNUDiubm41alkZzYUUYKWObqmveU1jhHdtrRED2fzFi4sKjbOVi/PKRYUMEys3NEOAEIwbIFQlHJ/BBcI1Xqg0ol7AdU7xkg2NF@AZmbhBfXHRQA4S5IXJH6pj1vp38Lf@1/o//YyJ9VMJOsHV9aZIl4Q/Sbq6vroOnzVJFEOLuAk/dAA7Brm6rqGRgK7AVBelU@n6mrvBU5Q2eYQ1TGOzRoGngEAp4pM0KV3@EP9u35g2vxpJYJNAkhbDZcBGY5zJSJUWuEzWAox3tKIkVWivTaKFq4AgPWoSQeRzlYq2zs16Tq9UcqFlo1ipFENzQhRLN69aZksrFMp6LidJlUomhAU5sRIZIQrTN9oV7OSVuISZ5T1fzOBsJH3aIimUhQcPxPBjKFvDofTggVbKvHs3cWo2O5bXbKJ79t07oSngtpxqKQ/2TPHdOyA6Scn1xGcuXxAWZY19rNcohZLrQak2wJtpqj5Ns2/4RhB44ltrmBZwQ6MvSKSOOpNxvUbylz/4zncaySpu1CDXnIYRYCosv7lZyNVqhRyYC0UouJDgO3/EXqqkSdcJVeDFZUIiGQ@9tOKGRK7XSfRn8U22VYOO6uPFrq7j1H4sl5fE1qUpXYFL5KaVStyR5QpiMVUKf9U1idXWWfir1@vZVG59Y/3hKbA3Ny8kqpUro5pU1eR19coo46zVdaUdfvYAjxoZDx5kS1CZxUylEWs2H22fbDfxi4m4Jg@jH0NHotAxXG8desk6TTHmS6d1LNipqjaSyXLlITW8VsyzeLISQspJoPesWKIaiPt@zOriqcMxxbtwr8eHTNvIwsAK42psSBukNjKsg2vMHnO73TVwhNZjLdwO4Ju2HX0s4sL17M6F1THXYvGjJ9u7eydpHXiUuL6/vZvWjz/biWtozU/t6M3iWXR4vrf96PAzCHH0ZG/7eO@Tg8/3PjsCdz/2@q1hmoY5Ms2L5mh08QY/KGA2zSG4Tq@m2bZ84/VrY0gXyCmcPF9cfPjJ9z785B9/@OkPPvz0ex9@@qNffvWj78H9h3D/gL9/8G9LeXz@8qt/9gcffv@n4Phf4P7PcP/8l1/97rf5TfY/hfvPZ9z@NLxn4Pgdg7h@85df/fBnv/zqt34M978I7x/fvH/758vvH3139Y3hfvgHt8P84N/B/Uc8rgj2B7/P3fB9A/73Odxv/fjD7/wH/v@L8IfGn374nT/FR2j5pz/@iz//8J3/pOvFv/jXH773gw/f/eGH737nw3e//@G7/0j/8Lv/WsvMPv7gw4/@@L//yR/99z/5P@j/h/T8o/v8P/z4n/7Vv/@r//ev/iS8fw73fwDTz//qPwGu/s0f/wT/P/zjv/nPP8H///0v/@aP/8@/@c1/RYbf44b//1/8W/786@9876@/@8//@jtfrXh@79bnV/dw/@rvweX@@bxPPPcp19d1@erXys//TG1MUwEcoE83MB342J1Lk2YsPh6XYx@zeG0dLyDL9aJeTK0DC7peKgFtPiX3TQRhMeinP/onH373NwD9fwciA9v/Djb4cwt4fZ8s7Isv5jxZimZB5NQXX6BnKDZ@MQv1fXB4pwJDnnn4DiC@IG9@sQkYpPt/ERjAsRAsgpvPAMHgNk/u/suv/vnPyGMSFp1/Yy7KTOQ8C51A8HdRUb@P/X5amlno7yPp@PCTb3/42T/68JPf@/CT38TBQc6V0ttpGN1vn@gFwPw94BCwcB84ANRQbAQxfy2mg2FtEycnY1rq1SvI/RqYQOpaj@WzYItpNTJraIaAKbBRJONxCp/wj@VKDC3gMiZXeLMUeO2k8JPeqdi4Cn4Eit8CZ2isFcFpjNMLVYgXA/Ew6WYR5Bk23qFYIGQ19Zw116tjHjCFDjWKAdEmhk7PBU0XUsXqI0iwOn7EMC6MPBV7Be9X1VqxOq5hdO8pCxBHageSBCj81HhqXHsP9irFCfCx8aP3kJViNZWqFcGlioVMUWrpJqWp5alwVPYUo3KjO2O43XLrIXQZQSsKfPoDqpKF0PhMTaEREMDBv5FaD4tD/8hI9zqGh3YaU/1wN@6/hc4UPgSAeGUZd@nBLcuYm4fgPeZRpShZeKV4DFBzKWKkoijBgTiWVCxF7ZsiC6QPefh61yaSCowOi5NIJMC0WROyQvMQxEiQ17yzsh8YHq4iEi9ZZkKhJKAzbnnimzkTRyRvrj9ah6cG/7012sBMZamsxxJJnLlI8qxBWnIq6@bcOC9GVEayrVMRUgTIPgYfvB8@BDPUEb2nbjjZQP9U7GU8xuLU9tBZ0vwJL6VK7jNdiRxeVmOpqZ1mtHkIRUkr6XT4VuhNDkpoUMg3fCsJYhkZF31orZpphRyTYiJ9NEvCFmqbxI7Fnvq9HXcMYkdaENJaAdefpHCq5qSsY2@N7ZUz8PyWWy5X32u5jRi8yT7Cj3eFn5ECvMFPmCubm9j@tSuZ5pPQCExrIVarhUvvTIvVjvdOAPzkkGl6RmEgslzlNvRcPpfXs4VCfkPXcoVSrpAvZoGyFjJ5XddKuVypWNq4ntTWQyBO6fJ6K79Z@wc3rv/tHyy7lrviFat9wcYKzaFfx2p2lW8BTeAyvNDICBWa3KK6TNQzafzp2Sw8IZ9pLb9xurZmX8lY7AbtO7zCjQ6Q1diVjAPfR3Cx2Ecx9hE4wQVp4EIkC7eOHBxWwm0C@A1OvlVA0PKAyNAODcBkHh206NXV1cwdi699@WXAajUQPeSD/Vgc@mCfRQvjstVR@gp9OrMz8kzy7TH26ODzg@ODw2fKo4NjkAS@xfRsRonFr6@vu5PlHLKa7PDwMIbED2S8rIbhr9tsNBqRbwvs12MjNpy9KsOYrst6Vs5qspbF/x0GHf/3h9fhr@MTQmX1GD9sZ@PRnWjKrBR7//79mHZdlA@cINx@oeeK6M5i2BEewAjzQOPGfGFqzKBxM1S1UIvRKnMd0O40ht9lq5/GNtWJ5wlqvXgGbQcI77AnuNk6cNmJyzf17pjtFRC7fYO@NLfruSDp/fowO4Zzxr0eWfz4/cTrsYH6d/2BFfRXQHw2HOAxPNP7e4thb9CCDOJqDwfYgYdnu@4ygA322dGKUj6daMvBDR2kLgfAnx988vhk5n2yt737OFZgO4fPHi288iFQnj3Z2z@ZWDe4bxQ0P4niW3tPnixawxdQ0woJ92ssvxEZNBY3AqMqpJtCneVOK8H1lrb54IGWUI@e4PTBkQf1aLsqY4338ubncq1Y8cxx4IzYZyWgbbU9aGqIZNer7iS6QJ97Zh36GkjWp1BqnEGwTaXJiiHBS8Se4qbRksZPQFl@jA4i4ofL8COFQQwP43fw4@Q419PCr4SPhmylI7zQCY2e1evDCHHhRgCxlmEwuL/uBeFnJX@opVsdAp4Gud3wsZeA4y4Fq8syMYW6u14q5oulrF5MF0vFXF4r5PNpTU9rG8WNEtDmjFbUCsV8SUsXc6VsDgYQ8M2XNmJxoKlWV1VhlNYEAd5liNZp47c2NvGjJa7Sr8XifIaNvRUNCdp5Yh8xwYQwAn71zQ9oX/y6VRX0HB5ayWoMYjRYm8X393cz@/uCsIMWXADYzQhCBy35YiazsSMIJvnswiCnC4LLw4AXgAXcksns7ArCiEeAmnsEoY@WvQKKEIJgoWV3e38f03mNFh3DA9gZ9@EWO7JsAJiDlmyWZBBBeDOJDuC2eUI5yukeWjBN9NnnPrvgJwifRPnJZCCG5xyOx/A4Kuv2tiAccMv2Nvp8SgXP86x@Ay3bdAmCBxZAQkHogaHnmaYjCC0wIioKQhtM7UsD3PC7JqjNxQkMQbjkFYRVJAhjgjbaZwJwyqE7JvP48WOjH3TMHr8uPf5uQ9bAxxqP9vZbn3zS6vVa3uX23ifP0efTTx8bry9HXqvXCoO1mnC5EAZ8zgaXixfk8aDZNOylPt8AH2fBp3nZNDFvTeMN5Cm8epjIoPkp@HwKPktmKcc8NrgGANrCa2cA7x2jRT7RRT70HrdaQgURNbgcmjiniH3mzAFakB4Ybc@toH1cXWNJMZm@rBcypxVyZwORSVeZyjX6d0X6diZymUiDpKvL@riaOQUZakMPj9eIQmOs5y0hvTbY0kr58pqxpem51LiMypndbpIlZW1L1B6svxWfSVt6NlcWGltbslDXTrd0rVgubLxcHwmCVMbnVnaj/BZY0STwm/iQ6hunWxv5mSAbGylD1csbG1LlGiokgKGnNQrMZlMUL0zjTJIwwzjui9IVlZZdUkmtSlccp8dVnit2yaTKuKpVuF4BllmIjIliBzXbjPA7dRKjSHsMohxvZcpImkVBKxUFyIOqipKEhAlJCbxfvYjWniavGcOckV8KK8v8M5dasSApeFqj6Xab9Kkv9moWEvnp2As8WkXHqqMdkCQC@eXYCbLfOBYYDPVntfDLunTWHgRRro@J8TkZbaMUi9VC7vOIf2SoElo/ebyrAEMa2lBLjrKPH1R3PQU/BBzM@XANLpHTCYxtymMT9zW2I7ddfuBZ2RuDtIGHOipX8gv5ejbEMTDZPA0881EhFQF4ehrVBVkdZlRrYDI6IiXPDOmCitms1arN6sAcDINLEL/44jUUKgr9bDRgO4zD4kms6BxKs7oD5c9UHNSYZ6I1MY6PY7UO6gPaqe5cjcrIOV5XzCp9LV6I4@m1Lac6cnyjax6ZHh6cOjiEAdvEE0rt/qvGHgLuQl1fXcs1jznTMhz4vIomx2AoQ1eYodCjWc1cV2ZzLRpyrSVVetU6gr7Dx6YsCKeyXH93CsJUJVaDHli5jBtVf9Tin1TMtECOKlTG4KZt5Cp91qq2Xo4rXnUInD@r2FCJMxINMyoE/86GIbWpNKvjaW1kq3UdZJpMOpJydNwVl9YzpbSuwZgKYy2EhHsD7Dm4NbjBX0MZSLRFkFmEdGacUbS0ZmppMfPK6ryS0oG750CDZMplbBdoUrLC25BS@rotdlxmbMrUwtDHK5RtI91nQyvdFyHUc9OwObgkM1F@s1VI5TPQLStvIM9eQuwoO9JWrtIRd1hTAgfgEeDWWSFX6eKq/0tpvo6BklXENanqm2@oRpFeUHUM16BBQknPHw3qGbZW0NJXclO@tg0/SGgberk@StRlDcqbedfbFL6sCafQONcgbcfY7KIRsCEVcIvoAmdcpqzH1G2InKVtQjtqJb0SgsSGIaUSBRE/uM234YrJ5IaeTErJCk5wrIF7SOmIJCWBRiYfaFsCsD5CWSjp4D@lbzdywIWmAoh217GO5Q8ZiE/xq9j11fXm7F6hb7DLSyMlR9YHjPVSiRhTaTVfacbZGplkpUbTUNvV7d7z7UoIvb0bi5dpG9t0oxFrhMeWmayufd09BKnN2kv@buB@GUg2Rjqi6uw0FAL1LBS6M2OHAvpXMV6rfB@JupmqMbUREwTq3nwdspiXeF7Z@zh9b4HtXnVDslR@ioIkE40y77b1U@n9M8u@KmblGkmKIou/ZylVoa1QTfV9HEaGa6rraN/bN17peah9x40cQOwMgP7BQJLPCzjhYr5iw@PSy42XxZdPPzv87HCfPcyUi@Xiwoxr42E6rSW15CZ7COys9XwPhJN3zM1r751P@ebAeCVeHiazuWR2MWg1Pq7mooVmUavVZG1TZ1uAq6wMNKqrFeTMuxpHvBp5FHTw@fAbP86NN4tg14FtLEOd5lN6raat61J8@OGrf4PH2672Pt9@wpKobOBv/@xn@sbf/tm/pDXN5HUF3fTsRhwg0agVNuJXV8Orq2u4uF8@fhrnecptSGDmK@5avKaGztqGJsV9mdsgu/m4/y7UPiLqmSL47R5ym1CA2oyX4rF48emrd4xtguRY6/R6lk4mVb0xhZ0og3QGf/Yep6zey2uvqrWECgiA828lDBBNsazXarV1nBtnyVoKj2rqeZqir19XThmfA0FBZd2hn@mv4w/tL7nDuu@DPfIGK06PbposX9MYCDeq@uE3flfXC3/7Z7/dkN413zW/CbS3VCoVND3@q5tXPFRqpUN@TIdvHS7jwWe5yM9AIEl/7dOpm8n5T/o6OnDRpKbIp0/s2pZzBgGQWQAzfncXuIsyu@dh01g4lr/F00@huWX4ZiEX2fxLH/ft4ywhHv70y6ras4L@qEWnPU@8y4PgkM7CqIBHFoj7ZG7ZbksdGDjNQB9b80HQAgjUzT9yVBhB8SgLfYwWeVtU69EkvWFQtE4TwJpYLFEqxxikPMSj6Y1xtyvQmXbT7hybQ4P0Q4F/dPD3oINgqD2MTsxHh7XnmK3JSW2qcZMld/mBBZmO3LvE4/jJ6JAmVS0jdSAmHqER8NB4ePSLziIICtrw@@JCdA4BILouKhCO4OkT5NMAky@ST0NgGVFjTchTVGdLxFJU/lSUCZxd5g6Uj6k1THTqQAlRbjxmpQ2vR5rxHNQtBmmJ0KwKKkqta@XTNGdCqxrVN@kGsFDhEbD3qAGHSoIVSupiu5YHjJxWnNGNQ2wchZwtR6oa5gQAeYPgWXhUC4cnO9zWa9InFarpQPxTIr9QPQLqniOlTID4TqgimV20rIAAYMwjAAyp9vDMFK@i9ByqtkY9PIyCfUFxvZ5q@f7IzG8Uc5QhA0@4R6DA986B6mqot12lzOGB8kkpSkGf2ea5aZPKhjDbqCDM4J2S8Ax3@aBOUOTeCxKhDlTlXEmhFsRSmrs92tt/sn2y9yjNZC2P4HgisO1OYMWZyuXeKfLv2iO/H6IRBuHdV2kVchzJRT@dfKgmpTDrD2erPTWb4SgC/LwazgkOxWSVgnnmAL9lxyNmQ6ODtCpNYZxkqPUA1Q3wU3WWj1kZeTbiTVS5Uc@PxwVEaUwrjijoBx0IpXAJCsJgwUKmB2xAeG4AraQVUAMhdWsGgJGo04UwV1imHgAIqyzXuNIKYdfGj1smUf/YLLVNUt8xWPIEFevDkE@kbS1JdAHVYvSryY/9ZKUNDH3EarBzcSRdhSWwnC7mQuQVd@LuXEbtJ47C80oCVIgETLM0OcD0iz9PAvcxic@3xUC6Ojc89rYKGEo9TuFEfc@mc6FikutbhmBvFeRJwnOC1aAyCdByO5cKqpN0Ort9y@6Ib2fTGAILanXFVKpdrWalK0jSGwJx8odADE2U8qQKunXn3MBC2oVEtdFwIH/KumNesC@ePnkMTf7cJDUA9Zen6wk1DSyvVMEiGFURgR4dPj0yPN/0JGWI7/2JQCXi52jCRBRo7YFfz5xS7tMCFk3FXgiUs2cGYen9ncsTo/fMGJhi0kjyA3iYlAWNYm0aCpecKlYqJUERjbp1OldHVWG@cQXpqlclqL5ndistqOizyrVfPRd7UiWAV382iTwkUdV1ij2AQFUfHgu1buHH6R@fPH1STW4aDGOtLukVyVRrghyAKIQwpFlg2/OMyznUAapCWBXwM7SEMHClkkJtviybqlFLAiO7Mj9PXNL8oShKcorAHXGUDjHOq95s0oo3xYLLoVlFBz60fbJ3IqQhrDcyJXR0cHi7JKLF1UNUozQ4uiGloCHw8hhhqtXcgwfkxlXDVKt6JiMBalauITYfMFecyENe5dozqh1xUpHG0FqiikJXdNVw/AvUMQ@scCa/seV6MERUO8BLPvCBhFRRj/q5FVw@8AHbqpFaiwf8fG51LbdePLR2vvlF6bjwSGy3PtWEtPDadx0UzYazGfCMC4WzRUBjvTbHLsoE6pttG@rQOHPVXCfTLmaK2kbH3MibxUy22M6b2VILuMR2N1dsdUobxka@3VJhcAsoiDKw8PNnAkd/TLZ7v2RXMWZFPVPqdjXg4jv5UrekZ7LZXKuY72RyuW5RM7LZQkcvtkqt27m2aX5QCovoLo4dixT449XMXewGbQ9DS/8D';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@AAT"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngtputsle._ 8       $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50) );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=  (^);instance Num(  );(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

This answer is for esolang called ETA. There is also unrelated practical language called [Eta](https://eta-lang.org/).
We test ETA with [C++ interpreter](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/eric/eta.cpp) installed on TIO, not [the reference implementation](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/src/eta) written in Perl.

**Line 1:** `O` is output command, so we need to jump over it. `AAT` jumps to the start of line 2 – `A` is used to push the number of next line (2) and 
to push condition of the jump (2 is truthy). `AAT` is inside string to hide it from Pyth. Initially I capitalized `aat` to fix x86, but currently it works in x86 in low case too for some reason.
`g` fixes `v` in AlphaBeta. `af`→`if` for Delimit.

**Line 2:** Just `aat` to jump to beginning of line 3.

**Line 3:** Main code: `nthteo nthieo nthneo anhet`. First two `o`s are in Wumpus and Ahead code. `anhet` is exit – jump to line 0.
Note: numbers pushed by `N` [are base-7](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tech/eta/doc/manual.html#3.4.6), not octal. There is also `I` (input command)
earlier on line 3, so interpreter should be called with `<nul` or `</dev/null`.

`%` starts line comment in Nial. `%x:` on line 41 starts comment in Chip (multiline, closed with `;`) to hide Kleins from Chip. 
`#` in second `% #` is for SILOS.

Answer (score 4):

## 274. Klein 111, 12960 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退 @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet     /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._'4o'6o@]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeeee;eecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<PLers95 66 4 >8370::$/  \0;}Vngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrs94 Cr ~-<u Uithw;re!-  hardoc""?2:2FAC t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*  <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPl5m3O7mxySffveAdHoQqFA1CVQha4qkECzeWNmvDGrsRReeTyrGI3WuiN55ZXWjrDWYVtyWApHSK8OhZ/0A1p@2VBsaP7B7DknswoFECDZo1HEPmyRqMqPkye/Tp48@XWyafidX/wigQ87cruj864bsMDyA9by7EvL09j2iD0xbL@QX5YkhNryzgc9ywn8kpRgOmOOdcUOHNNugRsL3AvLsd9ZHvjlGet77rln9FjQMQKw2BCK7Vrd9733ATPdXs9wWj5ALjN2ZIBne2BeMKPpB55hBrbrgNcKYy@drtFrtgwGEJbX96yA0BcYoDAvKMykzypjz13PtzB60/J9Fx3XGNuwev1gVAVLESAMz3afbb34dCrwOmOfGpCyftcaTqVFz7FXtuW1pkLoOvv8dH9/2jXPPlNdh@3fTp@@zF56vtE1pvGvsK1B4B4E0@4FtnVuOQbLa@taftpzlW17xq0ga8yzjFbb7lqa7ZhMZR2r27c8hi6s7XpQZYHVLeaKucbWOKRmYtji2HMKbSV8mOGd@@DpXlpgtKAm@rbVYm3P7THD8a8gJn09N4ZHtOuT5GBCAoHQ2Fc@hG5ZzHfsft8KuCdk1/LIG2JmXdu5kDj1HXlua2DazjnAWVCu/UFAefIlE4JVWV/QsIYGlqBS4GCQhBO3Z8XrwgfihVT7fcu027bJC8caBpbjQ359jdlQd1d2t8taVhcCjLGbGea7bODHnJpdo6OZmoSFi7Gw3kWX2czs9xn3gmxAkvZzRWb13K9s9g78ux2fDfs95ts98A5Mt922LPbO6ncgOOu1pJYrMXjM/lTOItuiBTCOBbnbOfoSyi3A4nTakLQWa8bgIB2UZsqx4bhQfB5zjB6nBrM/otwDmihE23U1dG@5lu8kA3blehesaZkGZhsj863ztjHoQox2G6sD6MD2Wc@FL1SiwyBZEDjAskDcGJk0MyMYTVi9Vh8aJlavi@QCdR3W8pVnAH14vqjHwO4BddhB0meW4dvIsSCIbzktoox@xMtcyG280tmlDQ0PimLgEW7f8oj0CS/DXABKI6JV5cqzA6AIzMUWO7IMj516lpXidGr5ptFHKo1HCZG5GEOAGdGIMDc2knuH@0kgUB5CM/pAkN7y6be/JRlMq7DFRhl@FVkuS3svdtn14hmaOc8EIu57ipFila@Znz07s@A31JvZc@9GAqwSlEqXZd1@kDXUPiRQDSCBWQONaFIv81q/G4uYbUzVQazZcKgW1AYwAfZ5hnJmDjwPufu4UI0LyHTXdc6hPCGz3sDhVb6agyoA@mv5GWZdWkgDvI7cKyrh0w5QCPwDaIyz8A6HChS6HGiKokTDeH23OyA4COkH2B6hVCAoYjxos89Z27C7GAT8ERVPtWf5QJwYZuC0sOZ7tmO1NBYmg7iOB23xEqIzACk5QGvoxXgLJQqAoSJcyip6ffjN32mdnwOeLdN0vZYg18@B2E3qGg1KLHRuDAnWdYwuJQvgMhg7Dw4RXBpdu0VcznBGIgpKBMV65Q66LUYN9cqGJtcxgNlawCDMwOJE7g4CSGOG9YwLzhFtTrmQ8Z7RhIqlCChuyrbKnuxALZnQzIlm1N4gaBeZ2t9jST/7WtksKZsLZxYkLqWllhaz2fMyEJy2RE5gS95FOZ9vTXQVfmD4rt2S@qOg4zp5pppMNitu33KU5ASOZCbpNZMpDTm1kirbFVNr205LSW4ALVYh4mSqbFbMml2ql6eCx6MENFeIBpurpZgpGVkNNYrLbA@ECw042eeqMMX8XL@BRY7eWswZC2ba7ZI7JEh0Qbp0kUCAD2l@17L6Sk7TU8gmEG5mvtFjVk6ncIgMl@x6OplIpuNZJwyQ04mMYmM9tV1kW91@B@UNKBTH7wPP9ZB2TQOox8dOLQCRLsOaRNfUEwJnIZ54ZSWBazeBkYZ0RE2SNzkMryKjFBjGTWiyJVutWEMGJgBtOfBvceOui9IBpQl7HmAdDkZqnEPVQGCekS2eER4TuUxm6cIBhoLYmhYrqk0bGgE2N@DpguZjeQPw5TyHAWy8kcR4T88YYa/GRYNxg8E@zWA9YA/eiJkW8hxgPhbvUDCSAbU/H@Re5rZZTs0XCpNt7FYTC7zslvodYNLvsne2JMx8vDEho2FtELO7hnM@MM6BX7gOBDFM0@oHglFBTvwAWNF0f0OOqug8Nb8jLT6Zjps6kVA8GseBTJ7XnugKDeQuQmxXQSZD0Y@PBVjL9oAtQU8@FTsAXE5FLr9BkIkEvJHnJCGUAIDIrKFlDgLgakDAVx3b7ADNYuoczhd5JzQdPTjFYwfOrrajqDExevVxXtKykRMmYy4KFWv0Nh7oXBFVdcKBKj/ucDdmw@/NQOxGSYSOIOaqZQ0NaO8enD3XcWcghYKM0CLIpA@vB5DETlAoho4rFLuosUaSclRFUGfANaDlA/11gqDvl6CfsIPOoKkBpWRPvdFBcOggsWQDb2QHLjc3u24T2LIP7TMbxpA1B017OJUhcovq8CtfugQBrO2zCvTcbwdAdUqy7QPDJPcdBI55ycS4CQV/ywBIQBoUlNL2iRXvA1M5GTmmIk8QpZxhMrZdOQUGDBgVzbdQeJtM5lfgNJ1KBIsnRssiVNb3TDKoMZkU0SM4JUt6NJG1B6ZReiTL8GobXd@CrzPodtE6cDiXU7iskGLX0qNHwNoUis7u9bu2aQcN7ssePxYyBVuAMR6KTW2UmVIQ5pEYTGvAUABGdD8cWgvcExJ2lRRk5NHNRMSW57kejzfoeO4VIwcEk@KFuuP2kLuzVyRwoQQNw1rbweG96EupKzVmihBRn0rycjKpfeXajnKdXFhYSJaSVegxFxY2wbSBpk00pcG0SSaVTAinoYlCZMiEvjUKgW715E0txDxM1bE5DLG3f2f3FaNWKi3XM0ZNF988flNQztBjALSKH8CTTFUqaEyl5OoVZFRrtidzv4O93onp2X1RCN8yLg1uF6WwTMUAFed6ODAoo/Byd5n0Kh5IFzAYMDuKlzyr5c7qZ9dnrfTZTTKDoVNlo9KETEF8Sk8799wBiCGp2kpJ1eupVG0ZhI9mJZlLLilKUYVhHIxEUp8UU2mDl7aStKA3VM7OklCoonxqZscjfMNMPpWKigrSgQIPyNpKUrsuQvzNVD2VTkLYVDIDQ7dKMgklY2Ih@JRpbEsTBXR4/BkvmJ10WqLmDaNS/N3qTsENB72TwY8G794h7@I4mhGFdQcGl/L6AiB74ISwGnpODVpDr2abIR@diONTt81HRTv42nu2L1lDqq1PD/f3jisUTcfwL0CmUM8RNguyMpSK19KAG3QHLUuaBQNsA0zmOCU4d4CRn5smU11GYKrJExHrLkw2BxvwGhI8XaZ2e5NZ8DuQ3p2JPBAScqeQd8kvZpgkDj4zTVGU@8Cxd06eTUyR9S5AnmCm30XhW/V4BsCaXeKOLfpEY4wSO6AxmgMCJtAWyJetaC7AcR0VeWE4nHPjEfEJEYAgN5S2UJKwJ2AQcdsewpA4gfMpQvRHiRWl/x3XgcGppb0ibigzYOQ4W2VpM@X/Iy5IaaY/bp0g6YOx3zVM4PeT6M5kdgYIgQNls7N9UuVbiKcHBzSOvy@PIEqZhoPl17JpnDqw/Q4WL4wlsBfw2lCqOEjFyR0qtQNmgpR7DiVtDe2Aj1qhhZ9gkKeGr6RwnLTFxxlIZSgjY6LCmTsSYF0TRvgWyMroy6dL2J5zaXuug4Ws7QFqYEVlrIMp5LOKF8hoa@sgvzu/fGchhxK75azHyjaOdbpwTR9al@N23XOXLQEAkqamccI@cHCGE0Y5gdGHFmW/owLaOndhqD9Jg5YVzZmuLkfjTQMhswSvfQW9AJud6THAnDyfHHxnD8QQvZDLQfpDW46eKJMxLNN5REeTjQHEKkAX6QZr8jtWvzPyJsjJd8W8SUCTh9Qw@UyWASIkpEq08HcUNN7IuQu089CrFZpm5X2PxgQ4eRcfV0/kfkJa4c0GcpiYckbXsCgmkN6q8HH9IuM6y07wrWiqQG333MDIfq4Bi8aXhBKyajPZzyYXkllVxbdMXixfZdmWdZlFLjXGPNyzzJm4h5ZlZtEXOzcWGmYWT@g5p2jO4HHoBdnk37AMopDT@T9Pp5GxU@qiuHmioZM/7QwsyTI7LpPPYIgRz5kMHUQHxsoqlDwIgDguiYKJFSEpcAcwrGtZXbtnBwc0Z991cOyiEfPWkGsJ3x3gN2MER7YFAjmfcBh3MjivPu6jnHMOfwycnLDCEF/jRepZrezSGNtz1/VgXOkzneYU8lHR94RH1vX7LS0YAgIeao/6dz/s518c7u41jrZOn1ayA9/Ldu0m8IiW1ejBYLYLzWHOg2nDGcI9oB3bcXs25ChE@e6ie@y6ARcecOHgYU8CA4Y4nu02nh1sH28dfykSRz263Rt0DUxjaXEKIMJxQjB3ojHdpguyhTOYiwmEi8Ptw2chlm@9fHaw1djdOzo8jaH5atC1DX2Y7V@cz8vQtxCE6VqOF/1htzW5okPD1IlZBMFscMxVZjA2ZaoKbxXdeKQ4KtPQA0Vk7B5VFWeBDZzn9lhez62vt5pGsWittsyVlbW20W61VvJ6sdAuFvKFHLzWVtct9p7AVdUa0swNmPisCE4gYRyQePro2koo4cBQ1ASJZTQzXZHvHYkzCwVrbWXdWDfX19eN/Fpr2cgX1yxrda29kstZq3qu3SzqxeU7ExdLBopWY1uPZoCg1eFkAXkC81PgM9EceOJB1rtirXw@v2oW2uvL@VYht9JqrucKxVZTXzOa61auvbKs5/WWmddLYVicUQUu0YEKQ6nSAdE09FJ18ExJYWcar2JaZQyXoQXDWVxGFtMPl5Fx4CA8VtBjIBaRcWpWuBfQPVxCxika4b6K7j1cQB5LsmSNHAVgkQBxHVnzmqHjOjpGK8gTa6vAKgX/nOU/P5DAfK3nbhD5Fa5Bx/J3revkfhm02xPOeXK@ULEr646dl8mZr0BPrv2KzN7ymgkc4VshfHzleia@W14zgSN8BY4PV7xno5vymQUaIVslZLhCPhPXlMcMwAjTGmGKr6qP/YrkN29JXcQ103tuoAj3OuHmq@WNr/hqRUMsliM18wZyCpLYMxfk52c2ztu3J1qMFI3AzyQ5nEaYnEga@@THyyRMvZy9viPHEXFmYDsXLg2cI1Mjp@kFxBKh6F10b4dsw1CDXhOgtxJ124f3X71mm14zALDTnZ6ZIw@a9hRdP3S1RvaYPjgBOisFk1O5E9E3rfYARkHZpu2g@R4wdb1IkO1m054HCiWBmw/C7wywEjsewEg0r61oejjsxaUT4Nl8Hvb04JAAmwYN4ibn/9lE4QcDL4BQ4vtfv9uCSrhdRR1jRGPByNBwrCuij/bcGhNB0UKv2bU77vWpYMh0H0rTwCVXoxsZZqOm2lfVjuH1cMglqhsIFF9ACXfQGk85n4sJv7MjKTEq5Ml1BubYPWbOgCbYqSURHhkNsruu0aJi4ENh26JAHlY2rwZryAeFMYEHep55Ec1YuWDjrQJBZxAM@Bt3B9xXjXYff3c1UQGZKxhN3QIR2Wja1h2V7hkXg5argqRHWcaErc6AHeeeJuvUdte44MYGGmdnn2fQs8/PQZ4Q33lgVx0Y29CgNHtFn/vowncGfl9tQmUF0HDIRk2hd0cMXpe/54HYYv9cZJhfanaXXg@o9Ii4iFxApKOCxi1NaqzQ7Kli7hrNEQ7VOx9PZRghCTjAcypmOp1bxm4vWvuNb0WaHx77Sgq/vj47NN9MxYtk1vAqyzdRqXwCmfIstlXdU7HQcdk9o6vmWzHjXI4eTh2PTTNAad5GNbuGD6QViOqwLqH66HUXuWPPZMKwyxub7iD2cXLCLQDzVpMF2xKt2nS7to9NuzuPg04vwI3jxO1s9IpNSduzCrZFMpPfUSPTbL7gmgEu5c4htAdwOb6KiuvUMcrR3HmFZrpX@JsrWnTcS4u/Z3d072am6gEcS@0SSdjmzB6lZd5HqbgdiF6zy/FiZroCszvTfbINhFMc8QHaA@nat7uuz07ofVexnHsQjL9nU3S8BG3DUWk9KG6eHUwkqs80Mcs6p16N7rnbXS2eZw14za38gdfGPkF8H8r9Iu6l6/dzr1A@ch1dfOey/Yusd3Ff3dHShIeL9jHjHT3wLBYmFiXnZxBGErgTZ3bm9nNFCqll@Xh5XgV4ZufKGIXfX6JnmVe6Yc/SH5G8DeIfBlgvgiHwuAz@y8S2cndsrYexp1to1@7LRKxyL7oWdGT0vlWlLJ/TPzKEnss9nFm1uwNrYM3kVYfNryzc337HKOThicqJbCyK2U6cEcK5zgjqnRg/PijV2Iej7U4GY3RtaOT3Sjoz@V0fZPQ@DrmPwHCEhtsBz51Bf6JyJ0ZxzvHdJdfphy3bbU0kEn0@liMV75enJgR536LfnYMrPhjEta3KSi6XE/JNbP56wnLXoGs5CvuVzd8TEZPLOOYxLM6GeDHj7DjGU6lQ9faFr@Kk5sO4U37ejAABr69nHduxghG@51XJLG7bdN3ux1QhMN2WjfIbSKW48HNfVd6SjcRuMDae@/Bx5qTZnjfrwTskMTqF0sOB913UEJ96fVA1q7hkDa30fMp69zxQbCL3vligm6fJJb51ojtf8BQzKrpW1NbubJFcnHWbVtfgn@Hqyl341rXlO/FFIouQk2ltC9fD@ArYeEU1McW3@iMoLLsFg5yO1bPIesfowGh9NfDDz1ygoYu/Gd4arTfOC9e3gVE4@J5YbYuJUoHrwLAsMLxzC8c1XVwVF67zmHM4qz6zcA96xrnFz1XdxT3HUx24dZiPBsfG2ZMeJb7rzIRgfOvH3aQAjenCGvnhdybC5yMT6nPQu3@qbqrdm7RR6b6GrmVnLibcIys6HbfjdKwO3wkU2eY1D6DIgJ@IuysTkP7zjsmIP8V3KcVLtut2uw8pWeSPnFu6bntmmvbwnFYLgn4U3pHRBA/xuXcKEPp6KiDq9Oe1m441gC7LdwO3b6lkmwfaxcki/p7HRcPFnV92FurOGQIokfD7y@K/d2x6brhBv0@fRr878OlFQVU6XjerKvcpmodQhR3wbUecbq1zt2l27PuS1LSMwLEvsuGMELfeObLtx0rBZuouOmtdGwrPG2lIDZW4/wl@DuZVqZhc4t1WZJhdxyW2M/C8EZZE4LrM77pXY/4wuX8imsblqw9omJcCsTI4w5ukAdxZF@4gu2MJRCwkziUwEsJR4FatHAgs@twZpYntnbHWsbzMX/Pkoqn8U6Ji67cfMyUqtj3Q5KAdm7kF9wn6mViMntlZOZ3BuX@b3fEJ@xaIWPiaWdNb53imeaqieaVCD2Q44jOvvPPdLG7fhm8Dam5g3bm6UrhzeYXg9K5quDZ8GvCBOhzMnTbr2n2fv5nazs8UGG4vId@GGs0eNov6aVltvhaCpvskvZ7r4SEiEClU07N8E6fSkSNz@YlzH8c9B86sdtkYOISdmYXbq9Yzqz/q8dQvXljnBm6vfGbjTsvuDKoArNOL1/ch/fbA8O1vD9zAmolvegH7PnTPjXPbfDpR8iGysETFHjz@mSB7dLpd@Fcd26fzG6HhjjknJDJOtkhnDZD3Z43Wpqbro4PRd0@rxAQlsfebqQcs3CMeGXDBAP2NmXHNmol3@zRuHJHprkl4O6CZWfGdSVWzNwHcFf3VoNcf@OIzO3bapxOfou5dkLt/ZQNbVN8CN2YdoxvMnsaOzcyCzCU6ybFxnhT@HbvrnrPvFHMMRDTotFEon0Fw29BdHxkBtAhnBgFT3A9cKMVJD9XjGXsLNGEtM9V27ODuCZ4gMGCMFH4xM7yzwVOI2Wf41p58LAb1dHaJPLtTgoG@fWR28VD8x44EONsFKjyhQ@tojM7Nx@leRGPtCIRh7@JYV/Hx2p2LPiXsUl1nEKi4y/@uPmX1zj6lxIbF1RhpMOXbe89fpuIUQttf75NDLRgIDvzuaGyau/FgivBsB4S1@bx4EjocTexapNLgmDZq3hNmq4@np4jl77qzRjxHI@h9Hjxkgg5k0Nu1TFx5vDfuF@5zEN2gK@sD0@0dW7hlYIqXzA6IwZ65ptGF8mndG80JoZ3RV4wH10bfakL9dsem2bLYLMS7RmDMkZ1o4pBGgJHpXlqxu03L@4pmBGPmeYPayQQ9tYY0DJlPMLwVqoFpcoEbp@Um2sj02o7fd12Hv4kJ5@CjP7@b2UD3QK@Hr7hruH95ovebOUibzO3hJd9uYrX4wb152fWsptvlb8zCHHbg2HxzgeHZlp99ZjuDIbkxFWS32cMcvo03p63hNIffgcZ2ZcMYO9rdi5vV@FZhf2okBSLxpeHTkv/sMc3ETuKH7yrqGJ7p4tqZMHzkylnsSNg9fDzaKs23JjShUobA0AxzEOoVuCep3V6zR6@5Y5JYTR9bTTxy16Tzo4ExnCVETh4dE45Th7dCloYNf5UpRzDqSd3fkU0P2SZL3O7Tixj61UwyCaN7YVvmOyN1Dy@NWhHNJWcNGtHObEiTm@BAzOlaatDBPZbZIJjHMF7YF4PWA9a6wgWUQc/CNevJlZu5ROX6HaIId/YqfcRwPUts3cZdgtD0QzNyXXVrLskievg/3P5WFjrmxuoKnuAfDNVzYGf37wuAxA88R3weQnZHrh@07eFhH9U4ud48/oLZKkAQ@PDmgKaleZmA@nQGXT7fcR7b0dVr0fgOpMG2C6YusfDAUi3nUiUVR8NwudIzQj0yc@twenOofs/u0Cs/Wg8ED7Xv0zfb948Onh2ean1fv2PmEDf8Dewuru5RUkI3yCCZ5k9Rn9BetQcuVqjwwdW4ic/8/RH9jtG0AiNrzB3qoK8VzJb7np4@f5Yen1tmyk7Hc3tWKu69c3KSgZSzb53M9I6H3gcCb7vDucEP9nQ9NYMCXzq0IjiP682IaR6mUwsGrEBPT/kR2ntlJtPtW63TUd/6HDpE5Lz@A6NfnZvJF8alfY4Nia3PLShqa2xdW10JQT6HwTgeibp7VPKZDXIsyOcmfVP3QB@TLLD8Sy/5TwsnLCe2InxcID0XzqIJag1sPFp43iHTryxxuk5bEsTRMdJyFelD8TPiUCO42Z5QnOBroco2cQKUOvTwLBI4GqY5wLlHqEuNEaCiGOl0KiWJUE/dK9ZDfVAYyKeDzBd2v8xyoRGz1gGZjeBRlYPCFg22UWH55RxLpcpcKwo0cOBaA6vM2naIesv37XMHkhCmgBRaobIbrivLZzAwDEK8tRpbvB6WciX9hlWYXJJZvc5TjA9FsjfskzaqYx68tmjUK4tJVU0uJs@cEsslI3Cr61uzwY0JWEgsfkSCo/LlmupcUjMXlWaZK/MBQQUVZXUMpwVkLJo95N/jKmm4vqNT3OD@l3/YEvrDSE9ez/aNLhQIqgAEDtRxrzZ5vGFx9fsG6h9DHFcdXLzA2NWdLeZf4UIEVxsG1fVy/7QolBEJfYNgOeLT01EqOOXgGjkerA44YfDURIdkRcRRqDBTMGIf9BwQkVtBx9fYiU1npgfe@BSU0MLoBB4uhLUy7IC1LNxLTEfhad2367oXdDwOU/KXf8hVMNGBeHFQOYyeVK/FYsRz7zrpPTJNdwCpDpG8szxXgChYyIYZDHCXBWn@I/cUHhMn3VBA7WqoGYmi4eqRdrZOmLrHkqhTEDWZlO22srh1/OnntVy98jXrZa3/@t1s6loUnPyJur7qyxkWgpRvkLDi3gXwHvsmmbw4lHmEkbYAW3DEK14fqA@RExkqDAhpzHX7YbPBQR4pc4uoUShJUdBM9RyqSOqRYjwiWOuKVCTRsVQHpQ5SzOhDAwNrilDzVldZVAZ84V89CVgBIkQ1UwaYuCo9Oj@P6n4wyOKQvWckGQCv0gs5sPGC7KKGqV5lOzxpshw/AZTdtZoD2gV/mdfyhQplZ7FR2aiSCaRIFzW91V6fDfM59Wy4tleHcaso1LOz4Se5/BdQ6q4HoR5nseXtvdi9XtSquffvfWPEZPkmWeYnloBNLF4fHRztnZxunb48gVq4CVnbPj@3GPIapCI6itxxu6RDD8oFB5AfwX8i25gNopbWVEqKHxolUFHWsiovcmOMNU2Evif4rPC@FfO/DSB4WttmUtQzABUYRGxYapj5QR81ATIRVmgzIyqzsf/ABhQVDJ4Lm8FLqahkVoHCUqGwHlhUbH5mN7nbQ0rsXix3F9vmTBAssSi@WuTPszizCG5@JfnuG77/9883x3J3vgnmjnwDaOQahtnfOnj28nhvMljYyRPXrawXxGlpzpyxpfFBaKi@jZSUiIC4caIiM5kCcKvozLgSWSu4siBbgjmaPR6YKJTSL0tjwoSSqaAe47qQQhSFUoDyDQoi04e5YYQYS2LYR8fQXfMsRkxgX45QhwnXZIE5Qfp4NXzCbCBWUVxh0zsiJi74ddKPiz@ZsMVh1rCPHvi8zc3pqqJex2fwH@uVQlO@zoZMdGd6naksD7@u5ZxDhkPYVJn3UWyRF4S8yNMuR@lFPaqQptZXBq1V0iElcQgaeumu0fdDYTDBXriBVWJvBy4pWgmZSSRfkApfg6s9pqrlynxJgQsMk0BeDvstwnewf1JB6YyLZsTf4zQ3cLCjAiCugVioQgg81NTNz6hzVaC8yF2hdTLsKmm@zxda5iIpwWeXtm/DmIkqoY0yThc4JeZGZBy1WJOKHRD9fZBJWtB9g4QSYFcLwolGJ2f58VnVYXICaFKLRMYMkyWE9Su3tRBCV3qFg7g3PPAiwRFmP4YzubGgqlBy57YTqqwuoQ5rmuoqscAb4MbYavJWkDAJJTKpnaDXjQHO0Md6ZmU//ObvcB2sZwGYfyjMw9w22H5d2Npg/o3QR9fB9s8iWx5sP@K211msstuKJ8fpjHSIzD1rDMT5RL6VMWQMofJuylBU5Vjdnx8cMd9EndBYoT0Yio/rCtlMOE5hdg8o45IqGsF5DON6HONRajiuBeICIkEZB8Uais/y6grqICxls5hwXMLUaIeyNeS7hkgl4dsBquIFSSy7Wlhd0bOQSPUyREhaks7xwCRHmEqVgDFKl3a/8qZpso2NDSb7ptG1KqtlTiDZReP1svwmSugiwEp8tFBjEAaCjEOAX1UEUxaNtJ7CoNibJfUkMraWy@kNREKFDACSQmcn1KsCMqcrigqI2bGGAYlNo3AUBFzbcWM6uENEKiDiuFFh7HSbHB@CxHn3WCvV4tUgv0IwmngqybMotvaanQVnTl0oDmZAfT@bQb8OmP/JDG3CnLJQb9RtNbbKtBJazA17cuK4uHyxD6llSj6bX87qq6kYhcoCFaQX2/t7QAktHDiGadlfuX1/a2fv4FuHRye31JkRZHIaLMmS1Y30maplavXIkIzSPVmo2/vZk@fb@2FRxlM1XkBAiPGO8OlkzoptOqVzYn/Fz5vejps8bkWk5x6KmGYf1X06WXEb@9g3GwPc4cfdbsWqpK5vavWN6pmTuBX9@1kqqhPaEhIXmM58UlCdnE4mJjG6juIUr6PwtVCZgo6aFPCIbeBejPUyCIeYBwcPsQAHkLRsCDWPeUICDvkM0FiBUJ7fh@ET6@OzRKQ4OEpRDPI0vDkDm9ZY36VQ9Ngx/E7XbkrQgbdQ@SlX0xTqIYoUPGl@v2sHSkqiKZAKikHAxBRxf8awNNRo34NCaqoJV4bdpTsyxJeSoBEAvuTRwO@wI7cfm9vatULTMUgjbHfAF8Ut9q1BD@Da9Dm2kMVaIJ@oEBgKKhkllY@qoWUJ1ZHDNKrnhPhqqEBSZFzrtQrKMKV1rGHLPgcGrqQy0NI/0UGsipRbYKZJnaSTBB7HS/hTPGYYL9KP0iA6HCM3aoZmOy1rqKBKrFId5FN0T169ukym5Fs0QGpMd0LFh1P6TMOGaASiRYx1gU41tvXo0owphbPr66hWDPV0QLVAjCeB9wyM0D8p7Z7RZ8qAFO36TGNkVc4UJ@MHXoqpVa6rx2HpNI2q4UMeIDUjaJtMRDhMwXlIJVuB2kFX32nh553dZzVd0@pgpkhSbBFn1HagK8e5qJQEoyQIUiK0FaxbVsIUcerVOOVBGPSXSPMfQ22zM7xJPyzNrbtYFpRrVn0c05g2boG8VNfXS6I2JlnNOgOyuM3ltSygncFCQikVyleoXYBSw/sT8KINXHUDtvDkM8txLCggoJmeAX2wMQAi81KZ8MKczFjfPsWQ4El8KvQ4QEIn9fDvJa@7uDVjMVumyZnyDfSpb86wU22LbnWU/R@zWrZ8rSx2K6MsCDqpqrLYqejp5aV0etFZUhYd7OofP8Y5nZtFkCQaGgyRhgCkLnZTZaBnkDwqi0550dhQFluV/BKFACsM0q4hwNd@VrteNG6yi4@hp86Ai8cbr7LokyrXnKbpN5A@bCGL2QzQzDVqvqTbcjD6RTudxjRoiw1MwNfZs5M08eyzkyxNH5WFNJo974nmNsVVo5q4dVcQL0DhLCoaGHseGbs4PtMIgcda@Jdn@c2RPXjEn@GKAKNN0ZYfF//lSZ@HMxbB75KkZY8rzuW6dKEAhwoUIlozRioFzOQXv0joq0xWFjdXl7uX6WQhV4aXXl5jBfbJ4ll@JcESTwwjgCF7dun6bLd4fsmsdn71rarW7Lb2tn50cXT0xXCUOlOSiZ3D17K@AqBrbJ1@D33WWH7Owz7uSSSWslIiu6Q/Xstm37x5AyIvPrWqVg1BtHqqpibrNWVNOPSqa2tLmdXiUub4SbIBaYHsppR8PnXCbDvLzuy@32rBz@3Q3VVKgj9scxPjAwP8M@HWG7bJONyyzs8He8aIu9uJAX72AxH2@XdevXqFhlf0sHfHInyCYxToEqWGUUhQIvO5/F/@6cJN5vqosfGX3@tlrQX8HOLnhzfP0XyiFz5ZWPhke3tlJQMFx81H3zn6cmtra2U3UziqFTZX1NzCxl/8@cJCPr@Rzy7UfV@vJ2sXX8j53Iqs/eXvJxtHR9/2faw7fJaZDkZ8F@Gns0KBXbB38Fy0Gf6T@V0rZjbQ3Gy/ww4ShOUKMZtksrCcPHmdxPp5l9B1PTGivwZlbYHp1c21//bjw7eJIFHNZ1958A0SbxOrxQQ3ggFsy6HtMlFNbCDY6k1ilK1UKmBc@2//FsJXvwV40Ge0Aa9qIcS1OkpU1QoFeZ@oroJBz@ch3v/7u99lT2rwyCtreXmzDs8SPhtSojqEpFWrB/ssX80vCeLRi4/1x2Rygg6IHWcJvbhy@ISstvXkMF/Ib6DZsfAmIBij0jhY1/NnTFSpLioWC0HHN3dgHTBjTbsJFoKOKYGFdMZeJYhqgGyIcrhZOBAxcYdX03CvzgxjaS29kn/ilF/FngnLr/45xgvXVheevNnNZjeq0PvjUyo9OWuIppdla0XZdZ/ghGCZPROuZXwNXVV1ARx@Z@So4iOKL1GsZBq8iMKWF/qwsY3FnRKiJFnUyH4JuD18/urf/9VP/urH9PcT@v1nKRFup1Jrl/Vq@AD9yFVPvj4TVuc5e84fx4F/@IVWdEEHMDlivjIRPdUqvuhf2MhE3yk34VONLAQxDjIXjoVcjOKVEl9nswxbALsMM/NkobRQLK2W8tlGmD3KBk85GZ7HcjfOH8/PJjwL8Ef/8ERWfC@Qi3AmkNvPAqs@5JnZK0iJWqJWr/MmXY3Xz93PsYY0pwlbI97PXEoJFVhXOn0MNMoEacNzlr7neQk/TWsIW1YbY01IiV/5U5VY4hqeelq9ualpr9PlsvgHka8c2fDhJkhacsVNrrpP6jequvG6mk7XKKW1qkjyhsrqVZ4BemuN1xuAPr1R26i4O/TTiETU@utqbWMyMIWvV588SWPRPgEE1cU6g8EG1MbNxk31prZxc7OxAf8b9L4RX3C92bj1T5/xMwdm7F/H@j@rZatnWdEmq3Wwa9kqumjZMzBU4Qtw0ClIiWskHVark5LCilrTVwt1lVEDWQLmlS3pS/nlbGH4yepeHniAj@B5Wc4uoeE99qAgA61LCRxNrPNBxTo5vPnwzf@Jv7MP3/xrsELa8DZI8m2@xb9n7/DvbYB/pyb@Hb/FP3b6Dv@OA/x73sS/Ix//Tt/i31YT/057@CclKoyBXLe4mevmLnP6hX4BBpvlQKzu5Dp6CzoflrNYbpQbsVzP1VtgsuAvByY712a5c5Zzco6ugycYApYL0NSGzzn8tQGLB392LofIc5cMYulil0b6vun7vsFSZ1KNJd9YIIxpupbTVu1GvbDaf1tL1suJ7NlZlkuoLL9SJv3uNzeMNRp7L3YbjSw2iLPn7uH4//CwF7fe@d87dJ8fuj0X/g8PD5@fAUurpp@k1SfwVKrpDfHZTFTLm2clFYk5JOtEdmPzrLqsonk1DZSaR7f0Rz5jjPCtLpxJMIJ/9eqqTP1u@eqyfFUmQ2TlhoYAEGDcAKHKor8GFwh39ipLfewVPJeEl2xovALP0MQN2VdXZyhnwqgi@ofiiFt/Bf/2/7f@n79kSq2egkZwfbOh0JPCv1Tq@ub6RryrKUURFmUD/tAB7Bjk@qaKRgK6BlNNSdVTNzfcDd5KaoMjrGIcG1UKPAYE5pGI4qR4@Uv51X4xbv6cJUFwgvG2IhYLz86GuVyq3ASXaMXAeE/rTqky7chZbOJaIYwx9RRBFFbKZX2Jm/Mr@XJ5RVjWiuVyUZgXFWX99lPNbeqrIB2srKRS5XJOwMJoshwaAYXlG2YZG3k5kcLE8pav5HDOkm52Scol@fFjRdwFtNnvpx4/1tdz799HTo1Gy/YaDXRffv9ebsi4eaeyXgB7rvj@PTCdZMr1lBcuXzZWVJ19kq9SDOuuB7laA2@mZ/PjODuGbwSBp7yz@xkZ9/P6coq0sedyrneW/PmPvve9s2QFt3OQ64qOCDAWVtjYWF2pVldXwLxahIzLi3x/kHKeXtdTN4tZmWeXyYvJhPDSi2spcr1Joj9LbLDNKjRUHx92fZOg@mMrhZTSHFmpa3AJ3fT1de7IVlaVYnpd/FUWUqy6xMQf9FzL6ZWltaUnMJwZ3n6QqZavjUoym03eVK6NEs5t3ZRNcesHnrQzHj9eXofCLObKZ1Kjsbt1utXAC0Nx5R46RIaOxKElXJXte8kaTUQW1us1zFj9LJkslZ9QtevFAkskywJOTQK3Z8V1yn/C9yW7jUduh4R16reU6DN9bRl6WuhopT5tolrLsRauQ3vMbbcXwBHqjjVxy4BvdbvhTSlXrtdtXdkta0FKHD3b2tk7zeRBaknk97d2MvmTl9sJHa2FsR29WWIZHY73tnYPX0KIo2d7Wyd7nx58vvfyCNx96SvvnWFZhjWwrMbVYHD1ln1l2w0bSq87sG3bNT1IRcOyrD6ARU/ZskzbN776yvD69DDOrT/87AcffvY/ffi9H334vR98@L2f/Pybn/wAfn8Ivx/x74/@zXoB3z//5p/9wYff/T1w/M/w@0/w@9Off/Pb3@U/sv8Z/P5LzO3PxC8Gx38S4Pr1n3/z49//@Te/8VP4/Qvx@@nt32/@6ezfT74//4fhfvwHd8P86N/C7484rhD2R7/L3fB7C/53Odxv/PTDb/07/v8X4g@Nv/fht/4MX8LyT3/6F//lw/f@Qz5f/It/9eEHP/rw/R9/@P73Pnz/hx@@/4/zH377X@m5@OsPPvzkj//7n/zRf/@T/4X@/5Def/SQ/w8//ad//X/99X/86z8Rvz@F378D05/@9X8A0v3bP/4Z/v/4j//2P/0M//@Pf/m3f/y//u2v/@9k@B1u@H/@xb/h77/53g/@5vv//G@@982c9w/ufH/zAPdv/gFcHp7Oh@B5SL4@1uWbXyo9f5/SGMcCNEDXmLA8CLXbI4smND4ZlqRPWKJKE0w451TMF9NLII8ura/HJp4AhEnQTn/yTz789q8B@f8WIAPb/ww2@OcW8PohWdgXX0x4sjRNkqjpL75ATzGu/CIO9UNweJ8F6Tz35D1AfEHe/GERGMT7vxEYwDEBFsJNJoBgcGcod//5N//898kjCovOvzaBMhc6x6EXEfx9mNUfYrsf5yYO/UNkHR9@9t0Pv/@PP/zsdz787Nexr1BX1jNbGejq754bBsDCA@AQcPUhcACo47iSLbAFKQ@GhQ2cz5T09Js3kPoFMMEQbEkqLINN0qtk1tEMAdNgIyTDYRrf8C@trDO0gMuQXOHL0uC1ncbr7dPSsAJ@BApWDDNk1SI4DXH@oQJ4MRAPk2kUYXDDhtuEBUJW0sessVQZ8oBpdKgSBiQbCZ2OZT0vp4uVXYiwMtxliAuRp6U38H1TqRYrwyqi@5qSADjS2xAlQFUwdcPq12CvEE6Al4a7X0NSipV0uloElwpmMk2xZRoUp16gzFHe04zyje6M4Q7NzSfQZGS9KPP5EShKJqDxnR5DIyCAg/9Zeklkh/5DI/2WMDzU05DKh7tx/010pvACAPCqKm7sg5@qYmqegPeQo0pTtPBJcwxQcmmSqkKU4EACTFpKU/2myQLxQxo@7tlAVoHoMDuLi4tg2qjKy3LjEMaUMHjzLkp@YHi48EiCZYnJq@syOuMuKb7/c/GIBp9Lu0vw1uF/b4H2PFNeykvSYhJnNpI8aWn2SZr/njxZYp9A3uk7dpOYml52V9wEz@ZGOi3nIcqqC7YlymKaEOHMA/2npdcJiSWo7qGxZPgbPlqF3GNNiRxeV6T02I7zkSKEpmW0TEZ8NfqSgyYMGvmKr7ZIEiQfBjF9dYVOvtDdcSmWovoxLRTEmPTcP992hzACychyRl/FBauUmMg5LeWxrUp7pRy8v3RLpcrX@sqaBF@yD/AaO3GhGlBNx/IsbWMDsVevVZpuQiNIsKtStSrW6pkuVU/2TgH89JDp@ZzGYPRyvbKWXymsFPLLq6uFtby@srq@slooLgNfXc0V8nl9fWVlvbi@dhOV1RNgTZnSUrOwUf1Ht57/4R/Nema74iNVv2BDjSbYb6Rqt8L3jC7iur18lpPLNPVFRblYy2XwL7@8DG9IZ0YvrNUXFrrXKmb7jDYqXuPOCEiqdK1it/cIHiY9ktgjcIIH4sCVSyb2mhwclsW@AryNlu8tkPUCkDHUwxnQMUcn/f/Pr@5JsOvr69hPSix85zsBq1ZhRKce7EsJ4GYdFu5KUO2W1tHoQt7WwLPI95yx3YPPD04ODl9ouwcnMMT6Eg@EaVLi5uamHa2akdVih4eHEnYjMHRe1jH8jckGgwH5NsF@MzSkfvwp9ycfKZ9X88vqsq7qy/h/jyGP/w@Hz8N/Ht8Qajkv8QO9XTxFFc5LriPHlDa4ipoqXifpGq1KdOswU1LXrUrLNel0VLldqdU1H4i73NKabmuk@cEIhtUt2@93jVEl2ey65kUy9LTxHio8XllZyHpZDXeIK@3UZn51rbSAuxfJhSltBm4FdHsdOhJYYb3U0sKon0NTgZD5Un61cLMhVNBVIeGYgCpGdy1SUXJcx7rBbcElow35vTb5dpqSnC8U5ZsnPatlG@wsh2fOrmeCra7KNyEcRIQjcJwcUXp4AQxuLi/lznKpOWFzEBbSR8mSNoSymyrthqgBt6vjvZi1@kaoBqcqff3110PagFQ6cAKxEym/UkR3JuGI/zFITo91biysjo05NJ6iyqIXUCPAox32DA8UBC47dfnG9W3LnAOx0zHomtAdz/X9vwfMtuFccK9dm@tOibyeGqg83e/ZQWcOxMt@D4@WWt4/GIa9XhMSiATEAbbh5XVddxbAGnt5NCeXzyNVZ7hpiXSdAfjxwadPT2Pf072tnafSKts@fLE79SkIoAJ7trd/GlnXuG8YtBCh@HLv2bNpq/hA91@mqakFVljDTcuhBTr0hBEYcqYh1@rlBBRMcANicrHccgab@uPH@sbRMyjN9QJbXWUrIFwvr@VKpcUsg8ZQvvkcslfZvij1cSu0b/WX/Ore8AjAVyDL7Gt1Y8BeQj1clT1rAQRHIA1omrK8CS1yf2uHBYvSc9wsva7zk3@2L9EBXLyJEm@dDSTUrtJyrxw61NjsDiw26LO5jvBBJzR69nknYMGVGwJITcNg8PvYB8Jb8Se42yHgcZDbLZ/uDHDcnWO3WU7SiLfm14uF4vpyvpgprhdXCvpqoZDR8xl9rbi2DiJGTi/qq8XCup4prqwvr4AcBL6F9TUpAaKB3c5mQdTUZRm@JUDrmHh50gbeQuVqnaqU4HPG7J1ipKDaI/uAyRaEkfEaT2CueB5kya7I@RU8rLWsM8BoMJMl9vd3cvv7sryNFlzS2snJcgsthWIut7Ytyxb57ICslpdll4cp4iFzOeCWXG57R5YHHAGqYpPlDlr2VnEcLMs2Wna29vcxnjZa8hgewC64D7d0Q8sagDloWV6mgbQsv43QAdwWj2iFUrqHFowTffa5zw74yfKnYXpyOcBwzOE4hqdhXre2ZPmAW7a20GeHMl7gSf0MLVv0yLIHFiBCWT4Hwzn2BbLcBCOSoiybYDJHBrjhRVWonsuBBiiPeAFhEcnykKAN80KG4Z5wx2iePn1qdIKWdc6fkce/0KYOwMceDvb2m59@2jw/b3qjrb1Pj9FnZ@ep0R4NvOZ5UwRrNuBxIQz4XPRG0w@k8aDRMLozfT4DH2fKpzFqWJi2hvEW0iSec4yk19gBnx3wmTHvPuTY4OkBaBOf7R58t40m@YQP@dB32GzKZSTUYNS3cJ4c28yFA7wg0zNMzy2jfVhZYEklmRnVVnP1MrmznsJS18Cw0L@t0GXIOFQCofp6VBtWcvXKsLKWF4fKFPlsmC/Ycmaht6mvF0oLxqaeX0kPS6hr320nWVLVNxX98dI75QWIHMsrJflsc1OVa3p9M68XS6trr5cGspwq4Xtzea30DsZTSRg04StVW6tvrhViQdbW0kY2X1rD3Xep8g2USAD9UXMQWI2GolxZxkUqhSnGXh4kK8ouG1FW7XJbGWaGFZ4wNkqVhxW9zBXFsNwtXC3UVDbAe0c5xnNAN9zMlXCtQpH19aIM8WezSiqFXAn5CHzfvAqXUqNPzDBh5I/GSiq/tFgvrqY0PKLUcNsNuriRvYlDjjciSK/wVCFpFAg3/9JQ3i9JpziQxO6A5Cq7ibelk1qJoTTkOvYYn1vU19YlqSrGUUf84riysH76dEeDoZWwoeYzbR/FVdfT8HL3YMKHa@UKnU6hb9OeWril1wzddvhZf21vCONmlHlDj2finJkm1JVop0/L12oDFzi@fXpxevqFehNHewJjSp4QPBNVJpUZqF0A9cTZLWZUqmAyWiBRUyqhCFJXVByNarXSqPSsXj8YQZ7DcJ9xbc5jRAc@z0x0VouCX@P5ReHRqORuxvAvBj22zYHokGMYrFHZhvLNlR3UsmqhdZENE0Op2kIlctuV7etBCUXRm7JVsTzP9eQEngzddCoDxzfa1pHl4aHEg8NF1mYWHv8zO2/O9hByB0XqG7XqMWciHYqhVpupSaeYFYtO@XZUIte0rR6X5G5gwKG8TpXfgs1bZEpL205trpRbyjZrpMAl96b9ps3ybHWlTHeKKIgJ2AGVHJaIkapUPwPEHO9FqQQJESRxATgxokWoEbtFPkaqb9@Uzys1hH6Prw1VluuqWntfl6plqQrcpTxKGBV/0OS3/@aaej63Wh6Cm762Uu6wZqX5elj2Kn0YTrJyF6pdTDnwswIG7huHQgI8794rH37tu6kNtVDhbmXC9b4LgkRDa1SG4wpartTyK6uZ/OoKTlCsLsNPz@SX87gTNpPPrWfyOsgTIGdAePitgX0FfgAD4kZex2kMpavIjMmZ3DCn6Rnd0jNK7o3depPKXCggBFKBpTKBu@cA1YADEg@QLFnha6TS@aWu0nKZsaES/QK3K1MmjUyH9e1MB9EcW0aXg6dUtrykdBcVhFk8HfT3avVSaW/Y/zZ6KerbzdX0Wi79LpUqKwssVfGtt1TCyBipCPoLQM1iaob5g14ttwCZhvan3kBNB4v6Wr5UGyzWVB1yl3t/viFX5TpU1Q2T4C@@3gvyVhncQh7IJbSxjDV266NY3bWgWvX1fFmASH3BkRVZOZPDYy1KMrmWTyZTyTJORy6Au@DoxH6T0B0kH@ubMsh4cklez4P/mJHfSgEfiq/qUuJGwjEsg0F54lq6ub7ZiO/4@4yNRkZaDa2PGTtPL0osSxtxtEaCLZBJ1ao0abxV2To/3ioL6K0dKVGiPanjfYPsTOglYGp24WO3/6Q3qq/59wy3v0G0Emk3rLE6reZbNo6g2Od4TGuTJSFfhter5fPL9Vp@Dfpy4MEhaD4PWfevJV7efL9YdiNdZdkzSZaJ@/DNBcVCiueCfZ2g9s52rsOZitJzHDgzxSjx9l2rp75@YXevi8sqH3wrLPE1S2c12vPYyH6dgP7xhmoh3N762Zt8AerFcUMHGGYHwNqhOy0U5BRjC3w7dT7aTh3uStgo46zrG9Y/WX@99rr4@vnLw5eH@@xJrlQsFaeWVc6eZDJ6Uk9u4EDu/YKLw7avnW99m5VZOdFPLq8kb63EnFUSw8pKuKVE0atVVd/Is00gbVaC7qCtr6q591VOp1XyWM2Dz4df@@nKcKMI9jyI0yUo6EI6X63qS/lUov/hm3@Nx12v9z7fesaSqHzk7/789/Nrf/fn/5L2LyRvyuiWX15LACQa9dW1xPV1//r6Bh7uV0jUEzxNK2spMPO9NXqimhXO@pqeSvhqQsxWrxUS/nuhjUjJ54rgt3PIbfIqFHFi79gu5PUnG1jM@q1ihoK2/PWElCg@f/OeMbCY1db5uZ0nUzZ7q@AWSzBuhX8cvm6AYeFNpbqYxcn3dYQOZwWXqtXqEi6MsWQ1jUe786T2oVq7Kdeh0PHBAd6SQ3@Wv4R/aH/NHZZ8H@yht7X0lb@EqWOFKtTtUjab/fBrv53Pr/7dn//mWep9433jC@Db6@vrq3o@8QtIxx3nLcNRHc0K4clJNESjQTbn0lPNlKUE3oTbZhw@HBviaBC1DXBdTWiTLlE4oSpoQCEaIIorBLaEp8YyJJTTEfNUWZIiyZWEbu/czBAOtoQapqHBSdfSI/SCLo9VgNVJj8aowKGHSp7Mht8deH0SIRUKp9cz7DEEgRgeoVqQBTrtJvilqpdZdul2UJ5kriGIhBTWs3wfNYMBO5ceQZBnQMV0VRXrG3hiEiFtB/izhiCUTvJo1SDuOsTd5QEa5KpQ7jlAhvHU8UAOSOXSIzz@RVI79OTM3gCAMktJj6AAIA@KQGzX2QZbTrFrO50ujxWJ3eDuRNQiYYTnsSQMhthaeAgxDFxGOJsrCxl4qECLiRo2rbhjiITj4MtmFRhPYHCyoSRERy4fjApw0dF7hbLGHj8ep6pSsVspRjlC/KhHDZWfjbU@3YoAkIWDsU9aJTnDnHQaK/vRJNlBiacpuUB1KhnGQG08GIfWG0mC/wcTLVLkVFWRRxkzIOqLtwoTigwCY7HzOjRRE5yeX0uxKPEmpN2kRJFCmWiEeTb8RCO9TiZP4o30i0SoolXCK@VjQyFBt9MH8hj0ZgO8tAu1DXBmII7a8etckDkdBGHoKBRkxe4SdNv2YFBB64ChahplWU9hsHbkQumgXYn5FYYbBgsp/FAohEYFJgYqAxHxLNC8N2lR8/uuQ9pD6CQ2bqsknW6@xHWl8GQPnCuD9IDxWGgXYixFXLkaUj7p/nK4gjOfh8UFx6YHI@SwbDLMOtdITU5@nSlcYR/OTToRuhQFogTDUNLAMm52rR4k6cSyGGqw8EvZ7DlIIoMmqax4bgNddfZt6DMcPyuuB8te2Rd29hT1S6puG6RbcUQygcKLHWmPEnohSPlb176w@AhXmTjj6rP8agakxwyU7PgHBVvCzh7PsebAO8Oh4LcGnzVuLGZiYReUUer2d1lfUBpYo@@5HiYPrwC7NJxY@dLzXhLjUn/khwfY6UQl2LWI5ULL5KfYkniMLTpeKYmT9hU6Ba7hdHpfARksPHeJRpBYrUuAUHUJ@xhgmmZ4IBRbMeT2EXUA1PagZaGGl8Ar4UnpCuo@U0xoeoLBO@wTtpyXSBMe6Q4QR/0BB1Z9ZRI7@EFQzIcftKBiND45AXwFWmevBX4JVHjEyQ/Dh9SNZtJ2NCZvtiDQYadDcVUYbxahpRCzYOvguusg6wvguQopnJGSBUVOA9q0nJI56ij8dHBO7RLxkhK7jSnDEIMoasCCosK24XMlnEI9y9XVlUYaggaerVk@qgH28WrDbP/cBhHWzQZWry9ucLHx@i1xteDYpHI14HgT5uaQLqBcfzziX0lq45nltwPbs5Rk209iH3gJvLJ/3iP1C6gYwSe62bdJLbap0FqqL8gsX89ch2RWQjJTi8kbRMIYohlmRhkzA8gyTfMi075qlYXHJbU7QA6VZYWOqLzPCy09PzTZ/XYE4Qa0wTm0N7sXptt1UfSQ@QTsOGqewxByFFqFvW8PIZBjXbEtzzNGCvmnEBrpVBmRdMNG0LuTDxihN2HXXMeVPayN6hPBh1Fw6LuipVUPlS9I13cj5arF0H/I/YfgP@T@w3GkYbS1YZ1LXuh0g9lB4kZdSiEkohmFMDdcM9rYhzCDXMx0jgIhRxNuN/AzKxQ6LG9ug3qshIQBNEEKCRXUhFg7qzu@dbVUT2fPgaZlKgiocUBdq1OZXrUiM5Z@97Lbd/0JJwdVDUHnI9KNTmZHUAOnFcxjVEFEGLy8bNRIc97T@DQM7/dFhgEDilvgiRLAVqDYqXKkC5Y8gXBq8riMecJqIjF1ErKEl3ADqYgXPS/YOKJ6DBG6R1mCZIIPC1uOUPIumMArD@/DDWFVuoWElNom60koyammwllKmSoplipVDZMJxY5SaWU6K6E/VEVtyiuWzRtR//HkL3x08tvQLmanngiW9wtlKd5UrCEq8LREc6FSZdVKrF4hBdklo2t50EHtcTFUdMoQzVI2HE3weDALXPGsEqt8M8Xrh86OyI5cikhhVKlAFkcV3ix5uwiLlBd4FMwXwUYhIYjwnIEAjtzMYJYINowHG1YqnHGw4ZxgV7FEDimRQx6EQw/nJLIugsEgKVJtitVTR412IFDJgE/nvSVqb5WZb1yiil72FWqggcFTGOeY5xAVCBpCSRrpzKzPjL0WS3SMaU0hQEK8haDF75QpSdMMT1cjW8SjeFGGPIrbBBlwXgEERiy4zLWMKRGR0VAX5Ho5Tf0AtF05XZNkHfeF0V@O/@RM6Bj@9NuOuUlIfdIxl5n6@wdxrGPJxhpoTMjQcyvIkHHAskVKV0AsuXKZMkN4BvdseGlwttl1m9megTsv8Hbx6CrhVDgeILWKT/puYATuykqJD4Jsoq@XApzF7nPgYwD73HFhqBHXYmhzrYtOEpVLmu65Y/tWBi8v5iK4RbsEuFZyKS73CqPrS5KYKuTDUkTNCQhF10YDL75qNBTf6rZTpUhFKFo1pMNkUsLxLJhi4YEPCaSHfcXFm9uD1P04UcWnCHZqmxfKYV94JiGSLQbMygR5Hnw7IKow3x2PBEn3HorGzUAhtfIdt@eeg3iHejUx9BT6gzFuTJDR71NaMszAIWoppgiVmoNiZoyUCPrZRwdln@UVIxWFz08imCiMDPOmyxhL1psRXWNudDxYGN/Jx6f3JJ7ek7vTS6Pq6TTzoXaFe35c1MvKGAMAjpOxfH8yMkKN9a3kTCQlckYBigd4cBJbtLOphSndAtAtAa61gT4ykc0n5Toi4Z/PK/@7KzAMvvfQ6jPwHsCTEfCbHm6gU@hWAj9cQVQA/CCFvOd2dBFp7z4wLoDFux72UVYAeZUYl4Oam6Bh9mEY7cvRCopAfA/N4/alW3RPe5oq3HNGmrzLDLvIz6@i3UbL6hojq6UIyEwMb5jjYxiZEb96WMaR0RHTc/mgToFOKhVX@4yFzoFKc0jGyFzGlH7fguEgdkQ9NPNNKTyYX37of4s145Rdhc8@g8CfTCZIPzyp8@@P@iOu8bLLL6kRfJT3P7wm8QTt/QUC5SA2P2TG0abuYp/HSpSlB/QIEaw2mWXSbRV2W26vf7sOP66I7s8pVG4sUCWs5Qmd3PNq3L6rxmNUEdIkX@95GEneR3QPprkYqXFkYxa283FdyC3MuOnBNJU4Ru5yZ425zi2egG407@bM6VUaMxhqFJI4XWDTuJrki5SEQ@AD@OIE0ufwRYTnVtDgBBXmDeeoxC0vjHx6Rj8mtQgXkMYBS6wUw5sXKBkxKCk0A/j1TRSnOTdO81ac5kScUQuYjDIGJJkTUYpawOq5qwq6VjuYw53RCwfJ8LmLbcPjuIaH0xLXSTtZsjMseZksAUNOWsnSngJMOdlKlnbJ4CdLJ2S4SJY@A8O4bSXfJ0ths0AAD6xkeILugoWj3UyWdpTUjRTg5RhhvFqyFNUpwGxyK5UIFAXmG6RGXDJzXJHNwLOgYyOhMsOQYvwMjpNowiVDvxz8cy34/LYW8MQ5yyUCZmmmT3QasR6DxwPdRqgfdUZLLonefO9wnzYNja8ZAP80DObiYQg9iOGJ5CQz4glDX1qhgC8kEPlmaXaKmD55F8UDkiNiBwqlSp6Mn0pPI3mgpZB/DYDrqckrDkT4sL4mUfAKfFg6MfC8dN5KThgdpQjXWFMzkoWF@iZ5R6awrqfu7@C1H68hmrueBMJ7M0MQXkuENsbTQYajxTaMrO/2J4mEfHEroB0PQ7NvvFEi9U4FI64gWuYcb3IWOUPGEG/8qbuyEwuHSZtgQehZy9V5K4v6BeLF6DXmdTFJlTc@SEKM50ALt8wLC8l2VxgJjrObDPUV87qhMCyPkjjXJJuEwBqqAhkYAY89GrzuoYKQjxu@hiGHOKmiIIJYyCgWzl/dj5DfXS6/hwJ1WAhTEcwSrGd3pbfF6zt72amUd8fR3q5A9Myw3dRM4SiKYVzkMDqISeZ30dotER@3cHAhn0caYZ@S9sNii8YE95Tb9NiC40IpwbucdLzIg@NFfn5B3ZZIupdaKLRoGJPAwzMepXSctbvTyjM@q4rRhyayje5HV7A3WcHxykN8lAFvqsh5K8eTnLi2NW7bpHwWXZCl6iXGGTktf0bVPHYEdk9LsdEyLDgcNo53D188@xI63bW1tZToo0fj9GGrxUnVqB/nmGnDctQfzBi25DOofB0Xr3Hene6hXThz5Fu8hDNrEAbw0pmQ/EQbTwleFuPnU20XwnHYWIkKXBfjZmBMcCUUdQzssm1RrgEUiBUoS4ZAEoq3UN4ZGq2lcE4WqAPvr2s0qPtqNHAzUqMhejGsmnCFO/WLxEJ24Ht0AShXDX0lSXTqmu0esldPt07Z6dM9tv9y5zP25eFL9mrrxSmeWz56uf3sYIfBb@/FyR4bzyjgg9dl4IASynXXMq1eE1h2PpdbYYR5x@2PON9RdlLc/cTosaeuaeF61IZv9J50uEVzrKDKQ@3BcHQk7rKHhPbsIOBXzZmAjoSbFp1pw33/DGCbMKbt4Zi357bstg2wEo59@7blhwevWNeGGgR@G56dzHAhCa/uoK1AdG0b3biHV7YBPC7SABrDH18RaPs8gNXSmCi46PnoEjzdO35@wrZe7LKdwxe7B6cHhy9O2P7hMViPvjx48SmU58HJ6fHB9kv0IsDnh7sH@wc7W@TAE5DTGJ5Mpzv47kqChuBUKuYFLnHThb6RLT7rDGAgwbMrg073@Sw5cJD72EbXfme1kmUJL/XhJwppTYBFV@ox6y0uZYZrvrSfQH7p07U0izm2QbFBY6lCeyuL5grdHioIx4WH3ojh9URWmQ6MK2QeX3tEm3JatsXkHdxzgnPf/Fw5teUQNUS0ALgRVbgBpcJI234ymdkglFWIzey6qAyNx8Y3BQoLBn0Sbh0pS1RiYu8LIsXjAAcOzgfp5cgB6B4c8iLawOMAbDly4ABshTugKHqAe0FYQUAMgsMBsme2yh2@6vX3af2XrUUO2waNYosiTbzeqEoNNr4o3O71u3RfAp/loWuQDN@0bQriEzzeN9DthncRNi0geeCJ4uYo3KsGkDIwmzYuNYhtbM6AGjb4AjXgvh@jHfhMqaQ0doqbfSzH5hdRnHcNh29pGm/FIdpjRdQZUhGbt@3ohgc6YNF3iQDx1pXJdEThdoVUaD00HITcvhWjIfY80i1B4Zay@xKwfSsBvwwaQKROjHRM6qnoiCeicduClBXfBYrEeduv4/BAzq2BaU0ECG@K/Mp@9y4lCjkzMU4K9x1S6qCK8FLNDF@zbLsetHFiqz08roJc0Oy4/cDmdahM5mB8zxdAY8cGsb2pVCdio7s9p2J0XCcWaROoeE6sTSDKh8RKFM8XySP2Fbb16KIx2keHyTGa7qUVWzvL4CLSlYXTLyAI80sSsbehS2@F/CmNecfXdHFlsVLd3T5Tv36TwWsSOFvgV4OFmwj5RZc9jAuaB63z0QZED@Uu0dLCuzb8QRNDiz11gltiKw@RwTiwY8O47kmjHPnx7cO33fEsyrQ7Ob5/X@GhVORMnCMP/I4y5m4ZVgujzFCYOhN7PWK8ExILvF4JXTKEM@LXT/DYCdZCGUrEQT5CV9RO3nEhWEiYu@agDZxF3GIlqjvCn2JV2joRCpL0KPH6yL5Wtivpaio73jnCYsWphCw6E2LGS67G@0@ov7qFbvdudMC/H46ueGfqePfwUdh278T2UWlT0/Nx8W4phuvhaL@@Ay3v3H4ptJD3zHzEvJO8jS2i9Ig4M4uJaHfs3TG@uVV31PYADfa9OIMSIY3FNnBoiTrUWKrwAKk4mrFAdHK6u3d8zGQ@PoGwwPdwyNASbBBxL/ArQPjuWdshZqdFQlM0WI6Ep9BlYutadN7jjsY8s/DmsAohg2REeUTMYvLCTeJ6omchEYJ20xNDDEtuMnXXIQ/yawLxDaqoBeaVGIthUQalmdlM8M7H9uObukW5ZbhsHN@TTzumed@NV2d5ozii@OYf4xxPisyuv1dcPi6F8XABy3o7oAy3QJLG22M1dgIR9wFQ0yZr8I5qCasUN81zATsRlh3u8MpNSth/f4IiQuJCOJeFY2xdCMciaVw@XgzFHNp5iN2AgVs6hSffoQweIYsnl414habGnZ4y2QWBkImXOj2JUwUEr9@Uo3tglXE/WYkE8nhbW6TU1MJU1nF2VuAuzwf6BPc2r06zh@mogNveGZX6q4mK9xITMYVlPjMzoSdgXi0Ulu/DPZ2LMLj698XN@5Bp/hn0@jC@H6P0Rz5N7wPlHrzIhP5jArij6PhW@bDBTAUEUWdGnzKRd@qM4umDtPB5IUgMKgE2O3iF1WSsKTacStts7LxHimMnkFt5iDXhKKO81dwq/Zu7o0OGfG98Cx8fH29sCIR7BG9@ER2ui@laiTnh2dJJN8vzHALjx5J6Lh4fo9NId56Zo0NzfEMrzwx60jJbPANtcciIb6vNhFMMFAnNKmp45R1O6pWnZ/VUvRzP4f7Bsz22ROro2hNTkLInp2IsZ8F27koAsV6ajsBeg47ifeKX4AdpyIQooZjoUJ5CZZO6N21UIiAs1@h2BbHtU7BUfbrS275pOKj4IyPTbdGPISBNvu4d7qdmTajnyhPhIXF@31EgVEZWNZmCghvO4yKmSRS8NtE91k9JeLuA2CB5xwW5RlYv5lbXJcqdkwkyvdp6PbNkVmQGfa7h9PyBd9W6OHc7l23WZf2vmkNz9O4tY4UVtoy3Yj3majf11QoebVUYahUpsvUcEaxI4CapED2TGdNIeyKuJ7Px8Lu8wFJkoLFyCU9ATFEpW@qFVIgn5YJKr7ZarziVXLlXc@plPKsXpCtBWk8r6PAYOk9gLXxBvhbUsSv9RXy21XIumTdojmCUFJ39YHT2A/t3nOESe7Zpvpy2GUuPcLManiHRHOtKiS7/RsqUUP6RHtEhHh2PiNN0Mc62tGxIAZR@BoRVf0jvUUp6lNMG/cAlHxGRiiTE3tvvpUfhqaMcTRgASM2uh8nZIDxjGAXXfbjriO@GVnUujel41DEVQ1HDkMTt5DNZxiOAmFBx9KpWl3zNMswOJgKveXxPwdjGBr///Qa8aZIOd2oYHh18yNXRiOsb8OnTYgJGQYK5T8c3JMg@2nU0cBeaggrovAttdJdIEEQf3MbNruk4EoXfgALgBf@Ii1SamMEUghXIifyoH80doLa5yXE9riLgKUheKY8ws4ibx1cZI6cd31RGGK0oJnB/dIXFycsKHpEDVSfbrWxE8CkOTkVCy9DC5mNZUpWSVxU/3XEwJRZMDYOFwLGieHRvaeBEFox@nlvQfEZsx@p2IdG8LB6NiwONdBxXxJ@O4vdrGGc9Sjz3V2/5qxP@GvfniRpDadB/j4FKcSA5cT2Gu2HyGCxzK64KI9lEg5o2NZA4xrDlu2B9LXAb9hi4GlUlp8rIY2PCQ435vJ5R@9xnYSJMROCRf437C/rOi5qPUjkB@2QyfvxKooIs2hsrtpJMUanm2N1N3jlFPkhmMpQmYzw41jeRHW@U4sikYCcgoOE0PjXbamWMJa2HHIfajFzdeCJrQpjYVKaTwQ8d3mpYM9pIrJQozjQV3JDOF0I85L0QQ0E4kdBY2HKrYeCRCDyKoUWohTBafmjxVgOHrE038QoeY3yPr7CxTyYuhEvM9nzEUz7kmeeHkScLiJjugjy7mCa5CR774I4iU3f0IuO4R9MYZzOJF7FJ3ihOix@ZbuMs90LEJ@KMIuQUt8o98hElPQbQQ/KdV4XoeSP9IrskfWqACN3vWkO2haMIg05TSRPn0VHbqo/6kUhdiz/o97u4qEiC3RWdeBa6O/IFXE0ZY4wto2nSAW7c4fAZNInz4xBIY4eI@Qr3f4w9/ME5Xj6N6zaoFglYK06o2IEmbTkjPl8BbWY5z0@FW2zg80VRGMyfxxPBa463Hixpv2@YliaBLOaDlCPxrLZ5@xbT5XgsBDV0QZdWkqRvD2zzYudTXK5d03PLeqzILsVqb05bXhkflIJCCj3yORBXC/qKJMWWfk2@9Ksiwgx7hh3950Cb1iVecSxtQY9BgD4Ip77lXVotTZKOrWiNF/EiKePCIx6bdgeeyeduQLbCq5HxtK@f4atdQGH4xf6ZrwabtBSWkXBNaryYDFV9abewAMMDJW0XF39pPQJP9fPywEA9K4BCWUqxySTR0rJIC8kuPZxngtJAtSSxpYeoGBw3sE2oGZqokrqAiq9yjCPjF7nHUgLxmV0DD/lqsxKAp1/GJRAmIFwpuisNklgT/6g0MJGxcAndCGsmC9zPpbYCzd3ybOC@4wKmWqFgsbRDBZ8@PThhJ4f7p6@2jvcYmI@ODz8/2N3bZdtf0hI2roOTRlj29PAZcJdosZwvih@Cg7x1AiFl8pC2XnzJ9r44Ot47OWGHx@zg@dGzA8AG6I@3Xpwe7J1k2MGLnWcvd2lxHTCwF4en7NnB84NTADs9zFCsYTBpHI4d7rPne8c7T8G6tX3w7OD0S4px/@D0BUaGi/Zb7Gjr@PRg5@WzrWN29PL46PBkj2HGpN2Dk51nWwfP93Y1iB/iZHuf7704ZSdPt549m8ro4asXe8eM9gDEcrm9B6nc2oahKsZE@dw9ON7bOcUMjU07UHiQwGcZdnK0t3OAhr0v9iA7W8dfZgTSk71vvwQg8GS7W8@3PoXMSco9pQL1svPyeO85JhpK4uTl9snpwenL0z326eHhLpX1yd7x5wc7eydlJj07PKECe3myl2F4jxRFDTigtMAfzNsvTw6o3A5enEKf8fIItzOk/t/2rnW7jSM5/xaeojWQiBkSd94FDm2QFC06lrWRaMsKyQUHwACEDQJYzEAEJDPnJD/yAnmAPEp@5FH2QZK6dU8PAIr0JbZ3z/oci4OZvlZXV1dVV38Ng/wWCAOtrEPWIyIwRjlgb4FIr16/w1KRDjQAefX2xXN4/xppStSqIxUwYOLw1E4GFQIRT@1uqq@ff/HVyRfPvz58jp9fYTFvT94892DATt5gghOMt3gHrAOVfkO9xnGCdvEjMGtGc26ehlOdHKv60bcn2HJJDRzw5kS4hch2@EJoDnO5lLGcJb0h@gaCa9uB0ll89T5EPMdFz8tyX4wBODp8dfQcVmQBkXKSD9/AqrMzh3xkf4OVxnyEnymEmXbYnHQbvUFniGdFTTZ2cFxH3TzepeGBea7OM5@4TkX8KJQhm200vq03wNB902h4@YfkTDXjvhzi5f5UKk/6iHDvaHmjg@fZM6b7XopQ@yuyj0lxeLi/gCmZ@isc2RZch54qldqhZMND@FiwdhFFvCuCmNEoGuksI94vkVRJHgj63RN2oIyuLr7YaqAbFAMfKdEwgn8GPyY/eHGwXoB0ZrdWqYRGLDWj9yHU1XAlBG1A/wiyQK9DVRajMPyh65bt6tDmL3aHw7breToPpY3BDuy63j3Zm2F3LnthPj81lnaVBU8@0nY3qTBme1lIpmRcimPqmYv/NGL64@nWMHYDOkWpKvJFi3PSXeHsGHCUVwJRgacnaJBR53tZ/@7kLVpz5epGbe79C/Oe5xaGAyIeLSx4Z5Tvgv68uOAEMMEIUwNI0hOki1LJyqPDSUziG0h4hYkIcJ/W6quQ1nUgCSiyk6Bv14mr8bg3tVsPcviL1/WXB98cH4PoxNZu7Gxub9UyBiXruzz/fYf1EE4qgYSNYB0HPY0@WbPkEBQfmikWsnbC/sTApRImROxyPWj0EvEaTFhGOlAJBRl2N8LLVgYYgeeESAdHEZDG44zm16UzUxjATXXVw95cB1NS8QPQlYgHJFalP6NRm@I/WLaZ/nqKmw4JAwmLETotcC5YFyT3nGMdCUrGDeHsYJKio/mYUdcMDcjVReGxeHiWfglvW6MYcaQizlcadsoJjXg83wqlwyYGPLP/RHgh4uglsC94853wGzy@Ezw6QqcLorgevwEyHpuc6I9OnM7S6TMp@WLfhyFaWTE17Sn05nvSKJp74jY2AB/WbKCmXGDMoK/mCq4ZPJD5KinA9fOcpz4ypyIIB5ZTE46V38C5y7ojpdQ0Doj81ugSissyYCVMtRtTR0YneWfwKDQ5U2T6RfSg8n9Hmiwpfw8sTig9oZaF2fcgSlKpTCswX4kovRu9oWDtYiTUtF@9S4q5tQfmynRMdmmmfHwGSCCjM9Mv3hFKYcddQgBkcnRs2PPXRJxdBWA6fe54kh33Qwat65GrZK3QS8VCuYWtizypXXm9h4I/POWxr8mq8CvIqj5nw61Jsx5MpjlTXj2NHC7O0zgepVVygJgJT1x6xUGp85xVllmm5YBAJlkLTtsgH4Faenvn7tyqshAtU7Jfdrg0oaDofWzPYj8JzXyoOPo2DZDI6OmnBFqHgNpoJuPiIwhzTYqz7IdYztM2OUPwGtj4BheIPpdOyHpJacp9SnEgWEkSVJjAAqK49YpAWlpWb0zryTOJHGpa/82AMelD9mrpFEXG75AW2qfhi@plMIMm9x/WbWax0uqbYR5DE7EydktIfrzytjUcjkF1DLDf0MZ8b@YV1VtxOoSDaDIWuEFYz3pj8UhopR@qQbWJrXdaZhgBnZoW9WI8jNAuEn9Ql65DDABl9JFpYUu5wLyaR/e107E3Xasody/5sgc0IRRRIuKe2lI//sipmKCC8BkSBXuRMS4oJJPqwX0HM/1uhuMfcO1HFWjQDtsGSNQqknyBPEgnA4JkbMXc9dEwIo8GDAV6QAwlKuxIM3GosEZvCztJ2JKTgFki1Cj15KfXY5hUB0NBRQnjSu3AfFsFGEykUlWQPA22Z6W6SU1ZZnDd3mmMEbhnentaOecDI1KesRLhP9WqIz6x3DRP7/BJnPz@0whnD7zBvWxRQbHBqLPi/uminKP2ITDf2144bts@UdBk2sEI3W9k@gwHxIvadSjwfa0gjsIZWACtUm9aojIa7pfDq0HjcNgPur1hLwA7DeHQpyzx8HFGjzhg3fHwJqLrc@hD20rUniXPDB/DcGr42@xL1iyIrSgOR64djhCPZ/UrRoEgzznG@CmzXhF/j@axzkyejc0kUyZ9vJTC7Spe7c6865VlmXnnHgsQAbc/FynBR0RjOndknS2tLSRofiqB1camKqjAuyMgL9XiXSARbcOkWqwbsxB@YHcCLbM7W3zWnubbhCU4Rhyl8CjEC2gil17nA7w2FaTIZxgR8ExVdspWVt5FmSKeID7M7iZ3dft3bj004Bc0v7K@jFuWMQKJuI4GU4rYXhFQUGgLRf/1SEaTJAYp1uvCKtRPFdqYzpea/jy7ixoU4QNKkcDlLXAlzkgXDB@8c81tgMhpzDxcVHIq5xEsB6og9dgt382w4X3hsTT5cROXPWcomA6lZNdq9F2kagGV8NbMuehZu8kMgXz/jKlWHzpqcwT0l0WUWbc9uI7WXOiASY/XV9zWGo5BGDtz1JNQj1wUD0e5B1LvTtmxFGFtGa1bnndvnC8zmw@L5WqbSOvP8HFWy8y3Z45p0hSjiDLgITRf6dmw@TwRp34D55vfmN1Dh7tolsRHmUXFjHeb5z4uiu8xYFcvNGZKUdsRbLRm3p81oOONuyWIlMnmVYMkRgNFRmPGj1ZRc2QyVHo4hYj7pO1z9GgD5bDeNtDOHp87iTofDKehS/WnFFgl0hNx1vFMJsilUQeDLxAFjjVcI6SMwjnNz2grr1JoIlgwfuACUSsOC4kfij24yWDN8RGB@XfcBkYLVVASwdO@HeFgMPoNwQhEX5w7EvHQmBUqFzUuaWpKAquCUn2qJH2cHH6eNaZUygIpYIovIYXp0YJsunp4r35pXyAdlMC56bME8pbz2BlPrUFr4B/7U2OKOnBSleRMzaj0RGiQaIC5AFZKtx@yuYraX2/MHI/RDTKNwIDg1y7@WZMciL69VTbUxizT9gyTeEJunm2eKuxzloSh@DeSX6Yiq7pkuEIBIbcY8vsVKAHhSan1uClAyDo256UaKmMEGf0KTkt4SeimSTznku9IVEmwsWmlKC9LsWuXUVhaCCgWy9MkDQGdZXmSpBRY6Ja2xUqxvbw/SQpQiDXvM8VhKGRU0jQ0I8cEhEdqrZEoZxWVLwsH08eNTS/10fA3fd0tW1/L81@BPqaFZ4XK/NedcuprqtpqNZ01lRPo4dm1pj4CKTy7wUYq/LL/6OSJDV1uYkItIyOlZUgc9gBNqRu024rfR2qPzlxrHUOXZx/81uZXg29ESYGrfxpIXQlMf@2Xd1YHpuqGCLI/oc7poywu24OksDq40mOv0NDVOHoGfkCbtMOO@vb0@DgF6tqc6Tij63C8WS6XkYebNoa9DqFGT1JvWEqnLnUm/X5pdPPl@NtmiUQ/Xkjfj4bPtAEdwojAnIiKw3GX73HANkBSTF2QY6po6k86HfvCBNygxLGDUeOUgnWgaP3pmZiXb0/J/0NFyvp6iR3E/l0qM/luAtYzpRS9CwW5MSL4vaM3z4A8@KKDYdhmo4oKQ7msg5lg2fL8/Y@4gOA9JDRYhELsfUyik50XYb8/zKu3w3G/jTgAj27nMxwf2xnKnAQ3GOns7iQitNm8Ct/3@tapYUxiszoWp9clfSuEhndHiPvXYff5dOQ6Z392YFWBLq9hN9cQZjqvnK7jCeb7A4plPoRmPyj1dTByW0Sn@cSw0ssETp6gReuV/FLTJ5XEI5eY0Oz@1EjU5c0tEhQDdN0jVUBD0tPwUk/uSG6I65xPKx2kYZnLkDYhosrDcuBBst9PKr6PO52HCUVC8@eB/c0FIm0B0AyU6Qf0RDDsfyrAtD6egwth/Qbv3FiUO5ihgRkymact/y83br1eV09Ga2uqXj@Ah0JB1Q/q6ghfHByoI/h9gL9X/OrmZo1l7pH3EV4e6Je36gDKIAfnWutqfAQ/4ZuPp8IwWBuH@EnJf5KvPWn4e/u1qHRWP8BD@/D013/7j7/@@3@W6vLjv/DHAf04@7NJVCwWS09aH5@s3Nbw99nRRe5J8@zJ6CLXrSGXobj/ZhwF/cCKHi22MveckGr3e827Tk2Z6JleRKGaGC7pwj@@DxbYjz/y03mcPI6TR8RETbIH/dFVQNkVlbDv5@q5lRV42vNz/5Ij34m8D8z7D/BeeSjLCTSBSIv3/qj6m8OTExt2HKU@ae@dEDFy8J5LwcuRjavLrL4lsHCmikV1UVCXpnkY5tHghOkmspnJjflXaaTuHcXk0N61mA24KU2ub3bH88bUddQl/U67zvnys0AslaftZ7yHRmWsgcDD9DWOVZdzr9h9aC5ue/mFs8rW5kUhm81mzIVojRaJOaptRHWZC7L0FjrhM/AxrBFMGeg7XVDnIy2gQCRGNkvXZa20@Fo3d4CmNVlMbHBnc5Y@j/4m6kjGiDn2cDOYAupYaPDRFWQqmtApDNQNZg/dw4MG0PG6PRJcii9JjkZhq9eZmZAHvJEiqR3WSjwyt6o6CyfmlDNuOtKvx52kQCAIagGE1YOFzhfIxBtC2h5JO@6j/g3qxiJTXQr4t9qgATYBQaNhf9btQ2UuhVJFNyCdgPKeDFZ/oI/SYQ2csxmC1hPKjOYBS2J5sd3NEF0RgxbukOH9UH3E5GKFj7d/CY0S5gNqOHI/XAePgrj9AQcQDTvwCAs@nqLjLSxiwzVcUoWh0KhF41jfLydyYHXkeWrEKZGq8DvZfCf2IBck2cNy0Z3AhPBuzMiTnPh2TzhthFf7oSEt2KCezCSH5orZfQOt8hr3KnGfEoiCKYt0lxiIhpm67A8uTf95dzPC6wiLjq6Sq6lyfAJILFONPi5P1fFZAIedq3TzGO5wyj3ZwyjqNYFY0EUZJoJA5MMDYyj1PJfhyoRbcDsQCYyvVkdmRtn906wUTkd0Pp/b@whduwPNBamEuEGKe2Ih7t0hxsFQRB78GgwHBRK5zTDutTiAkmt/rGXxCPfFaZuSGnZ3RWA8BNhPM8BUw7lGF5LtYhrqpByiEx5WwPl/ZVTvgGgmbl4R0XJwBBpkmMOMznlCpKREwwlUQJoo0kaK/xYKPkoxZj/s9uJUnrwgMHDYOffiVpMeJ/klNtim7hxl8aCE3mk2IuFS6K1DM1Dw6m8gaHc8Ofy8jPd0Z3BV44snTU7uEp2n21nkDyOPdHPsVsMMBvLh9M2nR4gWV1zrCEQOoTzbaVZVySh8sgYqXJrI8mKVDvhQASIt5mlSOANqVOeoAeJ0bhokUricKt5iYGRueyUnGTVHXh4uVgkWhLfmF91SZILbjDnS8/H/u97UUDbHeD4ZJh@kQj6ANToJODE4GvNFLp2BN6FW1AUcD0TjeIKIdBzIIisKQtj0eJJalZp2zFWluy4jXCBNaUT4KPDzLGeP5VxW3d8k90U6dyHHR7o@6oNdrqXpjDw57yVfH/FiXtna1OXyiS3aeqNft/pomZzMMgETenSE5LS8Bh0kDwbE0B1LZnBul7GGtuG1lNd9Fs0ClMtU4VQWbdFIOjsmaAmROFahPomHJ/Gvr9MTtrTs9ZmXdN0q6AUBqMGiIgReSZ7gEaOPvV/LLEA50ANBwPFrQRTCcybDmodYmM7LqHswnLrl/Llz7uQrW7ueQ3ay0cOyrQgso2wrZLQ0vLJRbE9CZSS/9vuQRfi42Wu3w4HGYoWsUpv51JBiz9Cd/9GIu4hvuHVIiIeOJcujAgwivRBa0/NoHHSvA3r8eng6DmYnsAjRz1cDHs83WN5rWIzwTib68prnaL0NqoZzi3ZywhMP6iJFRQWg@bRiUg0Yic9SF5YQIFwgANdp@h@lO2uRwe4/@y6M9kzrJgzqJWsoEQdRX/LGyWWGL/y9xhtpG/wOeNO1bgSWR/o0d0216Aj4QQcIW285B6v6fdzpCQepfQgNHSyMx9dGc6686gODlrXJ9emuDDke@tK0ProUwyZuXTWuJ/24Jz1b6JbuF2aav/uYzEl9XfUd9x@Ty3CedlY/sNyzHszSxJYhQZVQQYwwXYplP2pyU//J7ZgoDWKqMOxHdYP4o3xb@8TYsHa/r00NROWwNmy0cYr9zFjmBuSuZZJ1VpleP04ZH9gOIAo2Y3VEF0@TaL61xxhHGHFDSJiYwf0tbPa/ZSOX39BuQ0IlbZdKeCbLsMTWp1MFeVWWTWzLqgVO4ZvHh9ehWLZiTljGq3VrHINp/u4G6z2WW0r7s0ilo7Zt3eVxaqKllEMdr2mR0ygxtDLbo0B9tZURW5MgkTMSYASms5R0y6fSl4oNNkogJbd5XsnWGpPp6RLxBkUsLJ55o0YsfPK09mY0IEoKPNXWQlVWt2Rhk3hf9OolK5hua1qntFV2lSygic66xAg3bHAvocJFQlV@HqG4XcvoxF9@NTKlCZCm0m0ms4x9jeiQ0Cx7rpsTRAtyiQj32CjCc2UsUXSbfQQNTBo2XxwMoNbsd7UyvKrqXRCLaV2YA8OD5B1bPWxARnNHxo0jjo8hTMYIqpsF7SoD/yPAMUipa3TopDwgoLKWMiYRnQ9DahC9jTdCIAtUKetlJGaolOVrgirbFY8qeUBNeAL3F6j3LAZxK6azcPgNFxRSOVZVQw4Q3r/60Vp3h1s61b@lLmmQyIlTmsXz6miEhwru81KXsgJl4SooXnnqZzqoyVdS5TUI/TylbOYRNIE1DcTUg8oo95o4eKMQumEQOdmdm4RhsX2oHd1/JP@3prGOVRAOMApCWWsHqJ/RFdA8wKIh0EFWmqC5p1EOSG3OziytJVHVSF0k0qY4Wa/gFVmqlzqEzKjQKh2p5AbVcWx5FZd6TbWHSGWXZlMuQoyiN4O2jsIWOsKNlyryLH@wuB1KULbcyA3N4oOSpsiUuLK7s7KipG3ksp7TMZYa@ilCcTtSxDgfyHmLOdYFIYQvifCypMA0MVrfaKn/gRNIimR2rixXRFC8JnpI4qEpJXSfDAzll1OHsn6KPnQYYjh33ohoQhLVYL8krcn8VILO0/MeJiWH3t8Ol/6kkXgoq8q93XfxIq/F2xVei@21ZxaV0NuAqw/@7bX4nC8dLE3WH7VqH75@xOsvuSngH2ZQOq8QGxABkPZR7Mld448Su64YxQ2@Nt2IX7TjJOSu3YblGIQtHWjKg50YUwySsuisA2wJYOAnLZjaSOfqRRSCiYlNmbfMJHdilykyzCzzV6MSEKU6coz7ERRH4UV0khO3roYtxgWABQq/dwgVgOzaCptFaBBxxjP8KWcqH3UYprAjM5l7oFYbUq30QdpDnWAd62AcxA9SsZItOQ7YVwMEiQIta54Po2JGnfx0lewhetnqg/Wy7Cr5tFcT9Ww1OwLdYv1nlvHb6mmJgxbKcUzLHZyo5MAnkwNIDAPUxwjjxJkvUsvecvv5at8/1Jc/6sKw@odXX1YN@VtpJWY1UWJaS5WYJIHkaqHjjfKZ9CQeYNoOyEJeFbWH6xum64N5o@sbLq2Pb2JXSTrJPKRq8fWSauOboeQwjCoVkv9xaUUoa3lOXzoyty@VuzihebyTZXj9H8vw3/cyXDK0QLTRe1Yaa@j/MfZ/D2OP@JX9nfJOufGr7fuad47NWM7cfqtSzmNV2f9s@3x6VD6f7m68@ks2zu5XS2/H8DfO/iW7tZPlR3iAX@v61/vsfnYPk23dZmcl3/fhUUqpH0Mp@1@aMjHVbA/@2d/U5W7NsvsFn7L/mN3fgodKtQotOZ8@3z2f7pTxf6f2R1I/7N0Vo3zcVeqIMG1kQeC9QAmRJ7N8GCVFHlqrwwmygDbH0w5SXPmh0AI1GINnptWdsugqwEAM/vA@lPu3NGyG6I@EHxMTogmfuNCwDxKrx5lgBpgqPPhDVdBqL6pXAjihsSZQS0garS6fFrdw6/pSMChMAwzeBKmZHMoN5oVLFSO8Gf7dL3/mGDyKZ04KBCO9tymr4o6siv@bVaNZfDUcVJeg2mfVIQxXHKrvI25LNOiNRmHMGn83HIRjgjKB7qCig9fstfBSwn7vBw7/e6YLVy0qqPF91OCzOVxQcTRTzpPPYWb1rskq@gCzUj/j/tjWhv4FghsvbMNzMvp0TbcXX02adCHB6Xh2Er8iJIoSgprHjEpRAl2uWboOMHCAYPwjYDFIAeJgPBmU6GI3UNjwrAxi718HP0DT8DJZ6Fq7AcnQ2f@DSze3RuGIjrhMOx2HrkkK@@034SgYB4xYh1Hzk6AbniASDwxGdOWg8ZRVX9PhmtiGJjbGElEc9HC5D6vA6GEk@6OcPv5JpFUKjxvTdT0OnlMXIUSy2ynSqQnI5fDRAroivDMcxkl6PjVuMtDPdA7CY4NB4qMhuDmY9AikOfZ/TTdiTSl5Qe1IfkqlyQuqiFozVj28RgN7FQ4m18Q75lrbs8qzC8Gs8yvW9eIU8brzTK6UdxwkKA6TOJsrO/hlwrGXtC@ZEegA0w9QrLklkJAHZEK7hddgKUTRsPk9AS2hVIIJifxX1N9k2lMYPTyis3sQdgOSFTdNBOOBt@1eRAkwZ6n7AXR3JlE@xarNSTcq8lyggxW9KJqEm9s7G9QgWvF10vawlUpaLUHJ42A8K1HjruLrvunFbnyl@uH7sC/RK9RsgvPlSUl8hjeaBZM@hbVsecQ6QMpUT4EK7m6e3x09P/6qfvr8KA9qyiYmj@hYkknrWsTlz2v0vdNHpAZmI8zC07fY3NpgJnejfO5z9Mhx0z@3yb5mN1gXEEVFXAN6IzfnUzaJs@CC1QjN9kE3b7bDCWpIo0bjdMOmTOiqCUcTV8/8bBaPdEVYVxZZMAVsAHmwY/rk9rgPgmch0Z2yAigg0q0RA0f2UX4i5zp7jwsFM6ee0VMBBGuhsM9OFuew3wPDM/d6MkhJ2xzNnUDlQMjh9j@Ltsc5kgtFp6aufLTjay2/XDPn9t67E@@juZK6g61wmXCnw4OZHj93IifTHCCIR1HO@sjk//x3zqvdJiA6fTf28OoF9cHXyNFFFurP@a5aNxe1YLBiyPahGIfT@JCRPv24ZjI0h@1ZkcC12odgVbfdD3YdI9f7CGv12lrL99e9j1DleIQIoCMQhuEplOjV8F0n9c4cESudnw/wAupVPLr33cuvXsCQY5xYGMVnf75YfVLK53KeV8MuBD6d7zt69fJP6OUfe0Xy9h@Ph9dCl3FgKinCaF9HZ@ULan3ewa6VcBaC5OyGsfQ@OpidBt2vQVtycwGQAMOS6GAcDEpvL5DzZTWMTUKdCy9nsWnkO@nBdbyPXZ9SXY3DTo19FbeR/97terUY/lzZVWxCFX61SqXHkMnHqKY5qvcGsFq/OH35lZ/bCxSW6i@ZFbm1pmEOYBRiGBdf1fE6qhTrgFQhror5tB4xDPy3lnP2033ZKwX7udrt7Z3t@YrxdEH5ySUM3HYneeG4sb84pLVxwgWzUejjC17avnh@6uQhL0Kw4MsBLm8zElp8iNXXdTC7oaSgJXD2BtP4/sbKCr3DLJPI96vlsoeIKLdQWoT3x0OxPLHGtdtx4LddQ8hg1FtyW1K1WC3xQZaoVNmqlje3PxuOYYnw8UL6lQhEiI9Wy/tePFsB3TD09c1LK6Anw2rqP95Y3XnVO/jn73bfbB25reaXFSfvfB9R2P54ZDdgHNwUWS0CGTsWrF1qBJ5cbAWlUfDDsLTRLrdA86xst8PtzXCnvL7T2gzXd5u7u7utzsZOs727HWxvtpolBHunLMXr3gC0JIfZH6vtPKzauxSznWp5t9OpVLa225u7nd1qeX19o7mz2S5vbHR2KsH6@la7utPcbX5aa0vakwEBq@Uurh3zEvjp3cpdZkG2S27v/wA)

Klein 111 code is at the end of line 2:

```
@[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
```

Klein 111 path:

```
line: 1  ch: 1..42
line: 1116  ch: 1157..1
line: 1157..580  ch: 42
line: 580  ch: 41..1
line: 1157..2  ch: 578
line: 2  ch: 577..558  (main code)
```

Answer (score 4):

## 278. [Extended Brainfuck Type I](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Extended_Brainfuck#Extended_Type_I), 13163 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)[-'][(7aat        r>77*,68*,R@'_)(22)S iii/ \psddpsd;oh]#####+####### +(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退     @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet/112\    #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"         ; L     xo;--o+++o++\     x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn       # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM       #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>_             #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++/._           #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                    @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
















































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  ata",_"[ x];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1PLers 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrdisps94 Cr u Uithw;rehar#8doc""}2:2FAC/'='d  xxxxxxxxx
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]*****<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8                     \@,,:1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                       \=#x=4; print( 1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2    )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                :~-<~-<$~-<<<~-! `=> $/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]+ pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*^e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*             <e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJkAQIsNn8uM17u5sckn37zoBodKFQIKoJVKGrCiTQbHbMjDdmNZbCK49nFaPRWnckr7zS2hHWOmxLDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIke0aK2IctElX5eTLz5MmTJ79ONg2/84tfJPBhh253dNZ1AxZYfsBann1heRp7PGKPDNsv5JclCUNteWeDnuUEfklKMJ0xx7pk@45pt8CNBe655djvLA/88oz1PffMM3os6BgBWGyIxXas7vve@4CZbq9nOC0fQi4zdmiAZ3tgnjOj6QeeYQa264DXCmMvnK7Ra7YMBiEsr@9ZAYEvMABhnlOcSZ8iY89cz7cwedPyfRcdVxnbsHr9YFQFyxqEMDzbfbr1/POpyOuMfW5AzvpdaziVFz3HXtqW15qKoevsq5O9vWnXPPtSdR22dzN/@jJ74flG15iGv8K2BoG7H0y7F9jWmeUYLK@ta/lpzyJ77Bk3oqwyzzJabbtrabZjMpV1rG7f8hi6sLbrQZUFVnctt5ZrbI1jaibGXRt7ToGthA8zvDMfPN0LC4wW1ETftlqs7bk9Zjj@JaSkr@fG4RHs@iQ5mJBBIDT2xofYLYv5jt3vWwH3hOJaHnlDyqxrO@cSp75Dz20NTNs5g3AW4LU/CKhMvmRCtCrrCxrW0MAShAUeDLJw7PaseF34QLyQa79vmXbbNjlyrGFgOT6U19eYDXV3aXe7rGV1IcIYuplhvssGfsyp2TU6mqlJiFxMhfXOu8xmZr/PuBcUA7K0l1tjVs99Y7N34N/t@GzY7zHf7oF3YLrttmWxd1a/A9FZr8XMkSm1XInBY/anShfZFi0I41hQwu3DbwPuAkSp04bstVgzFg7yQvmmUhuOCyj0mGP0OEWY/RFhAMBEMdquq6F7y7V8JxmwS9c7Z03LNLDomJhvnbWNQRdStNtYJUALts96LnyhIh0G2YLIAeIDYWNi0syCYDJhFVt9aJxYxS6SDNR3WNOXngE04vmiLgO7BxRiB0mfWYZvI9eCKL7ltIg6@hE/c6G08YpnFzY0PkDFwCPYvuUR@RNchqUAkEZEr8qlZwdAFViKLXZoGR478SwrxWnV8k2jj5QaTxISczGFAAuiEXFubCR3D/aSQKQ8hmb0gSi95ZNvfSEZTKuwxUYZfhVZLku7z3fY1eIpmjnfBELue4qRYpUPzM@enlrwG@rN7Jl3LQFUCbDSZVm3H2QNtQ8ZVAPIYNZAI5rUi7zW78YSZhtTdRBrOjxUC2oDGAH7KkMlMweehxx@jFTjHArddZ0zwCcU1hs4vMqLOagCoL@Wn2HWhYU0wOvIvSQMn3SAQuAfgsa4C@90CKHQ7UBzFBgN0/Xd7oDCQUw/wDYJWIGoCHG/zb5ibcPuYhTwR1A8157lA3FinIHTwprv2Y7V0liYDeI8HrTHC0jOAKDkAK2hF@MvlCkIDBXhUlHR6@Nv/k7r7AzgbJmm67UEuX4FxG5S92hQZqGDY0iwrmN0KVsQLoOp8@iQwIXRtVvE6QxnJJKgTFCql@6g22LUUC9taHIdAxiuBUzCDCxO5O4ggDxmWM8451zR5pQLBe8ZTahYSoDSpmKr7NE21JIJzZxoRu0NgvYaU/u7LOlnXymbJWVz4dSCzKW01NJiNntWBoLTlsgJbMnbKOerrYnu4it2BoQy6GP5WhkgAua4l4JwdHUZyYQ4D6DL9ibbqzW0zEFgYe0Cy29SSXrGiCLH2EuBYADrOdk/wCqCevS6rtESdfwS6cS/BMbaYU0DmHmATBvxFM8pxoe8dZC3OD50YtbbAWQJeBLgaBR0XCfPVJPJZsWFAEpyovjJTNJrJlMadjRKqmxXTK1tOy0luQHNqAo4S6bKZsWs2aV6eSp6PA8A5hLBIKexFDMlY@s7sV3kQ91@B4UICOr4fWCiHpbUNIAcfOypApDTMqxJhErdG7AKYnKXVhLw1DT8iDCojfE2hPFV5HwCwrhNTDZNqxVrmdCqAcGBf4O9dl3s8ilPWKHACxxM1DgDsQ4i84Js8YLwlMhlskjnQB0OQmtabE1t2kDV2H6ASQsijpUNgi/neRiAxqk@VqNIKtBN8f5@3AKwpg3Wg/bujZhpIRMBbmLxHgITGVCD8kGYZW6b5dR8oTDZaG60mcDLbqnfAa77Lntr08DCx1sHcg7WBtm5azhnA@MMmoTrQBTDNK1@IDgPlMQPgLdMdyDkqIreUPM70uKj6bSpVwhlnnEa1H6o9kTfZiC7ELK4CoIWynNcwGctaJQmNYPJ1CHAxVTi8msMMpGB1/KcLIRdOhAZb@XQuIGALzs2tNJLyp3DGR3vVaaTB6d46sCq1XaUNGZGrz7MS1o2csJszAWhYo3ehAO9JYKqTjhQ5ccdbods@L0ZgN0oi8DZY65a1tCA9u6A2XMddwZQQGQEFoNM@vB6ANHqGCVd6IlCOYoaayT@RlUEdQZcA1o@0F8nCPp@CRi/HXQGTQ0oJXvijfaDAweJJRt4IztwubnZdZvZnuFD@8yGKWTNQdMeThWI3KI6fONLFyBRtX1WYch6geqUZNsHvknu2xg45iWTlEMg@FuGgBRIA0QpbZ9Y8R4wleORYyryBFHKGSZj25VTYMCIEWq@QGlsMptvwGk6lxgsnhkti6GyvmeSQY0JmQgeg1O2pAcTRbtnHqUHsgyvttH1Lfg6g24XrQOHczmFd/4pdiU9eACsTaHk7F6/a5t20OC@7OFDISSwBRi4oRzURiEoBXEeiBGyBgwFwojeh4fWAveYpFclBQV5cD2RsOV5rsfTDToedOrkgMGkOFKf2@eD1hRWHXRDdMo4hkAB2QxA4oXxFZd7pohgElPTfS9LIqaQVDA@Z5oVJgt4lNQN0iFXrDFZRBNCYkVkLVaFCuYow@FC4JnY4rGFW7zw224Puzb2ksRHHA/AQN12cMJC4mIFSRXGTKkiEihI@k8mtTeu7ShXyYWFhWQpWQVxYWFhE0wbaNpEUxpMm2RSyYThNDRRjAyZ0LdGMdCtnryuhZCHqTrygiEOcd7ZfcWolUrL9YxR08U3j98UEBl0lxBaxQ/ASaYqFTSmUnL1EgqqNduTpd/GLv/Y9Oy@QMIXxoXB7QILy4QGoFrXw7ooI85vx0mv4lmaD0Mbs6N4ydNa7rR@enXaSp9eJzMYO1U2Kk0oFKSn9LQzzx30lVyqtlJS9XoqVVsGUaxZSeaSS4qypsKgFMZVqc/WUmmDY1tJWiAKKKenSUCqwE/N7HgEb5jJp1IRqiAfKO3ByEFJaldrkH4zVU@lkxA3lczAQLSSTAJmTESCT4VGyp9A0MHRlxwx2@m0RAQKY2z83ZAlwA2H8JPRDwfv3iHj5jCaEYV1BwYfD/ZFgOy@E4bV0HNqCB56NdsMO5GJND5323yMt42v3ad7kjWk2vr8YG/3qELJdAz/HAQq9QzDZv0AxAnDa2nQjrqDliXNCgM8E0zmOCc4G4KJn5kmU11GwVSTZyLWV5psDjRgtDgloLlM7fYmi@B3IL/bE2UgIOROMW8T3swwSzz4zDxFSe5Bd7V9/HRi0q93DsIUM/0uTn6oHi8AWLNL3LFFnwSwQ8N37VaJ7dOI0wHpGmgLhOtWNLPhuI6KHUE4OHXjCfHpHQhBbihqohhlT4RBwG17CAP8BM4OoeyHAzAgIWBggDAHhtqW9pKYm8yASeL8G4zEZg2FDrkUqZn@uHXCaAeM/a5hAgufBHcqs1MACBwom53tkyrfAAwjo4mBEc1K3FVGkCNNw0H8tWwadQ9sv4PohYEUdoFeG7CKQ24cSxLW9pkJIv4ZYNoa2qIvghZ@jFGeGL6SwrHoFh9kIZXhAAEzFc5FkvTumubAs2CggL588oftOhe25zqIZG0XQAMrKmMdTAGfhV4go62t/fzOfPzOAg4Yu@Gsx3AbhzqNXNOH1uW4XffMZUsQAElT0zhh7zs4ZwuddmD0oUXZ7whBW2euM5qiQcuKZoGLy0jyfGYKQ2YpvPYGegE2u9DjAHPKfLz/nV3orfVCLgf5D205eqJCxqBMlxEdTTYOINY1ukg3WJPfsfqdkTdBTr4rZoECmgqlhsnn5QyQnyFXooW/o6jxRs5doJ2HXq3QNKvsuzQgwqnI/mhO6SeED95soISJKWd0DVExAfRGhY/rFxnXaXaCb4VVd6G2e25gZL/SgEXjS8LhgWoz2c8mF5JZVcW3TF4sX2XZlnWRRS41hjzcxZmaGbCHlmVm0Rc7NxYaZqIn9JyDmlN4HHpBMfk3xEEUc7r8Z@k0MnbKXZQ2zzR08iedgSVZZsdl8imMr@Ilk6GD6NgtSwXMg/SLg7IomljjkgJ3AGPaltW1e3awT6sQXQcHbhoxbw25lvDdBn4zBnBoWzAa4bMt404GVwrGfZRzxsMfAScnqH7ANI5Sz2pll8bQnrmu18GpLZ0mVPIR6nvCI@v6/ZYWDAEAj7VL/bsf9vPPD3Z2G4dbJ08q2YHvZbt2E3hEy2r0YCTfheYw58G84XznLtCO7bg9G0oUgnx33j1y3YALD7gUcr8ngRFDGE93Gk/3Hx9tHX1bZI56dLs36BqYx9LiVIAIxjGFuRWM6TZdkC2cwVxIIFwcPD54GkL54sXT/a3Gzu7hwUkMzJtB1zb0YbZ/fjavQF9gEKZrOY76g25rco2KxugTUyiC2eCAs8xgYM5UFd4quvFEcUiqoQeKyNg9qirOaRs4a@@xvJ5bX281jbU1q9gyV1ZW20a71VrJ62uF9lohX8jBa7W4brH3FFxVrSFNW4GJTwnh7BmmAZmnj66thBIOjMNNkFhGM/MV@d6SObNQsFZX1o11c3193civtpaN/NqqZRVX2yu5nFXUc@3mmr62fGvmYtlA0Wps69H0F7Q6nCkhT2B@CnwmmgPPPMh6l6yVz@eLZqG9vpxvFXIrreZ6rrDWauqrRnPdyrVXlvW83jLzeimMCzwWGEO2AxWGUqUDomnopergmZLCzjRexbRuGi6sC4azuIwsph8ujOPAQXisoMdALIsDzNC9gO7hojjOTwn3Irr3cEl8LMmSNXIUAdcoIK6Ma14zdFxHx2hNfGK1GFil4J@z/OdHEpCv9Nw1Ar/EVfVY@a50ndwvgnZ7wjlPzucqdmXdsfMyOfM19cnVbFHYG14zA0fwVggeX4ufCe@G18zAEbwCh4dr@LPBTfnMChoBKxIwXPOfCWvKY0bACNIqQYrvExj7rZHfvE0CIq2Z3nMjRbDXCTZf/2@88RsoajfE8j9SM28gJyCJPXVBfn5q46JFe6LFSNEI/FSSw2mEyVk09OGyS/ZiamSnXsjxeLzt2865S@PkyNTIaXoB23MUu3fevRmzDSMLek0EjfIQyjFzcuf3mm16zQiAfez0LCR50BSv6OmhZzWyR/TByd5ZOZictp5Ivmm1BzDoyTZtB813BFPX1yhku9m05wUFTODuifA7I1iJHQ1g4JnXVjQ9HOXiMhGwaD7nfLJ/QAGbBo3ZJtc62ATyg4EXQCzx/a/fbUEl3KyijjGioV9kaDjWJVaX2p5bYyIqWug1u3bHnTwhhkx3gTQNXC82upFhNmiqfVXtGF4PR1iiuoFA8QWUcAut8ZzzqZfwOzuREiMkT66pMMfuMfPGXprAdZkPw@Zx3UytBPF0aXiNi7CEET4Iti2K5GG98xqxhnw4GBN1oM@ZkcPp/IULNmy85SHoDIIBf@Muh7tq1O7j77bWKkLmCkZTt0A4Npq2dUv9e8b5oOWqIONRkTFjxRlhx6WnaTq13TXOubGBxtnF5wX07LMzkCTEd16wyw6Mamg4mr2kz10k4jsDv682obICaENko1bRuyUFr8vf84LYYi9gZJiPNbtLr3tUekRcRC4gzBGicXuWGkOaPYXmrtEc4SC98@lUhgmSaAPsp2Km07ll7PCiJe/4lqr58bGXpPjr67Nj841hHCWzBlZZviFM5VPHVGaxReyOioU@zO4ZXTXfihnnMvdw0nhsmhGUZmxUs2v4QFqBqA7rAqqPXreRO3ZSJgy4vLHpFmIfZyfc@TBvEV1wMNGqTbdr@9i0u/OY6fS64zhN3JpHr9hktD0LsS2SlvyOGplm8wXXDHAFew6h3YPL8cVjXJ6PUY7mzkOa6V7ib66U0XEvLP6e3ee9m5mre3AstUskYZszO5fWzV4EnHgXT/OsPgj/QEw026rTUJfv1gi3JxSK/bc3awH3QtFrNvLPZxYmMLsz3ScbTjgjEh/P3bMx@HbX9dkxvW/DJRTM9/l7djOIo902HJWWj@Lm2dFEpvpME5Oyc4jB6J653eLaWdaA11yKGXht7EjE974sM2J5un43ywvlK9fRxXduX3Ge9c7vqjtayfBwg0PMeEu3PYvviTXM@QUEEsVdS7MLt5dbo5halg@v51WAZ3YujVH4/SW6o3nYDbuj/ojkdRAfMcL6GhgCj8vwv0xqK7en1rofT7sBdvWuQsQq97xrQe9H7xtVyvI5/RNj6Lnc/TlcuzuwBtZMBnfQfGPhBv9bRjH3z1ROFGNRTI7iBBJOjUah3onx571yjR0/2m5lMMBsoZHfKR7N5Hd9EOz7OEI/BMMhGm5GPHMG/YnKnRgFOke3Y67TD1u225rIJPp8Kkdau1sIm5D@fYt@tw7O@GASl8IqK7lcTghFsenuCcttg7blKO4bm78nEiaXccrjsNhzejHj7DTGM69Q9fa5r@Ic6P24U37ejAIFXl/POrZjBSN835PRNl23@ym1B/y2ZaO8B1IsLhHdVYs3ZCmxaY6Np018nHRptudNmPC@SIxmAXE4Zr@NEOKTtPeqYRWFG2igZ1PW26eQYlO@d6UCPTzNS/FNFt35gqqYjNG1NW311sbIxV@3aXUN/hkWV26Dt64t3wovklaEXE2rYLhyxtfKxmuviSmW1R8BsuwWDIo6Vs8i6y2jCaP1ZuCHn7mBhi7@ZnhrtDI5L17fBh7h4HtiXS4mRQWuA8O4wPDOLBwHdXH9XLjO48vh/PtM5O73jDOLnym7jXGOp0ZwhzUfPY6NsydJSnx/mgnR@CaR20kBGtO5NfLD70yAz0Ym1Oegd/cs31S7N2lL010NXcvOXHa4Q0x0Om7H6Vgdvmcoss1rHkCRAT8NeFshIP9nHZMRf4rvZ4pjtut2u/fBLPJHzi1dtz0zT7t4Rq0FUT8J7shogof43Dl7CN08IYj6@3ntpmMNoLfy3cDtWyrZ5gXt4uQSf8/jouEy0C87a3XrjAJgJPz@svDNuyKeGW7Q79On0e8OfHpRVJWOFt4yZONT55Qk0SVzvTPtndtrasJR2@PfZ1Dhc5hNE8@54BYmTtnWmds0O/ZdmW5aRuDY59lwjolbbx329mN4spm6g85a1wb0eiMN6aUS9z/Gz/68ShfTVbxjiwyzqaDEtgeeN0JKD@eiacqAtmSNzyyPucrk/oxospgvd6BhXq7EyuMMb5IhcOdeuEPtljUXsVA5lyxJakcJXbVyIOboc@etJraPxtrU8jJ/zZOmpspPmYqtD3/KxKvYVkFTkHZsfhjcJ2hqYrF7ZhfndAZn/k0myZcFWiCY4Wtm7W@d4Snwe1Q@r2joywxHfObVQb6bxf3y8G1AbQ6sW5d4Creu8VA4vasarg2fBnygXgdzJ@y6dt/nb6a28zNFj5vL1jdDjWaPvUWdtaw2X4VB010yY8/18NQWCCeq6Vm@iZP4yNu5JMb5mOOeAY9Xu2wcOAw7swg3V8pnkkTUd6pfP7fODNzS@dTG3Z3dGZQCUKcXzO8C@q2B4dvfGriBNRPe9KL5XeCeGWe2@WQC8yGwEKNi3x//TDQFdLqJ/MuO7dOBmdBwy8QVEhknW6SzBowcZg35phYKouPlt8/NxEQusd@cqfss3JceGXCpAv2NmWnNWgNw@zT4HJHptul/O6DpXfGdSVWzNx7clvzloNcf@OIzO3XaGxSfHO@dk7t/aQOrVN8Ch2YdoxvMnkCPTe@C9CY607Fxnjz/HbvrnrHvrOUYCHsgvKF4P4PgHkO3fmgE0CKcGQRMac/h5dNLtDhzonIu6b8FmrCWmWo7dnD7LFEQGDDaCr9YGN4B4bHP7FN8a48@FYJ6MhsjT2@VZEEGGJldVCvA9935rOlZ0IVyZQbRFrnbOzMTaPGYDv@jMdI/EKd@kZi1Ha5WiH7HsS7j479bF51K2Nm6ziBQ8XzBrcvp406meGsnU2LDtWKMVpjyrd1nL1JxkqE9uHeJuBaMMQd@dzQ2zd0OMUWJtgNS3nzmPBk6HKjsWKQl4oh2i94RZ6uP59eoD9hxZw2mDkeeFdx7NAY9yqC3Y5m4CHpn2s/dZyDfQd/WBy7cO7L48bQJ5jI7IkZ76ppGF/DTujOZYwI7o/MYj9uNvtWE@u2OTbMFtlmAd4zAmCNg0XQkDS4j0520YneblveG5hlj5nnj5ckMPbGGNHCZTzC8QaqBaXKpHGf8JprL9IqR33ddh7@JK@fgoz@7nftAf0Gv@y/@a7iJeqI7nDn@myztQaR@gB@dnFdcz2q6Xf7GIszpCR2b73MwPNvys09tZzAkt@IKU0Gcmz1C4ruJc9oqqYCBhhQusUbbjHHXnOCdU8MwkJMvDJ92IMwe/Exsab7/fqeO4ZkursoJwyeuycXOpt3B1qM923ynRBMqZghMzTAH4pTTXVnt9po9es0dvMRq@8hq4tm/Jp1NDYzhLMly8gybcJw6RRayNWz8RaYcwvAodfeM2fTYbhLjdp9exNQvZxJKmNxz2zLfGal7jatiLYqmrLMGDYFnNqrJbXogA3UtNejgps9scNtceng@eMaCzKBn4Rr45ErQXFJy/Q7RgTt71T9itZ4ldo7jrkVo9KEZ@a26NZdQETz8Hzz@IgtdcqO4gtoTBkP1DBjZ3fsMIPMDzxGf@xDboesHbXt40Ee9WK43j7NgsQoQBT68EaBpaV4hoPacQZdPh5zFtpX1WjTUA8Gw7YKpS8w7sFTLuVBJX9TwZolcj1TeZLdQ4VpgtVQxQYLLGurTUC6LgonvjLXcOJvEXa16liN2WFwR@1xnIffSj1YlwUPt@/TN9v3D/acHJ1rf12@ZxMS9igO7i2uM1NxCN0ALmeZOhb0xvNg6LN96hwcOs4@PdXX76b6GAeaky9dSVPjgOuHEZ/7OjX7HaFqBkTXmjp/Q1wpmy45PTp49TY8PYDNlu@O5PSsV994@Ps4A62FfHM/0jsfeg6bSdodzo@/v6npqBi2/cGitch7XnJHSPEgnFoyCgTKf8LPAd8pdptu3WiejvvUVdKrIuf17Jl@cW8jnxoV9hk2Src9FFLVatq4VV1KxfekwyLe86DuvPs/tPrJOkz5Z/pm7TQYliuWstzxbqrhtJ8K0dMNyYofEp0XSczepNbBVaBlnHTRlDf9XzZiu6/PwfGy0oV5ZYW5lTQaYJXF03Yt7rGNbYlyjRk5qAFSlzpiIEYf0SDtapHbHz4jjo@Bme0I/h6@Fqv7EWVuSWMIhLTgapjnAWVggNo1RQEUx0ulUShKxnkDf3UM9YhjJpyPjQD5llguNKFN0gCFTeNQYorBFg21UWH45x1KpMle@AxwI2OzAKrO2HYIGtm6fOZCFMAekCA3lA64Aw2cwEA5CuLUaW7walnIl/Rr1cZRkVq/zHONDiewO@6TF7IhHry0a9cpiUlWTi8lTp8RyySi41fWt2cGNibCQWfyIDEf45RoOXVJPGGGzzHVGgSSGCtY6htOCViX4EpTf45qPuFqtEzxb8Jd/2BJ650i/Ys/2jS4gBNVHAovsuJebPN0QXf2@4ZESMdJs1OVKl9TtLaGOjKubg@p6sXeyJnReCV2VYDnkE/VRLjjl4B4DPMIecMLguYmOI4uEo1hhoUy3O@g5MAZoBR1fY8c2nU4feOPzZkKDpxN4uJDYyrB91rJw7zYpHaB1867rnkdS4V/@Idf0RaoHxJHwMHlS2RdLETUM6KReyzTdAeQ6BPLO8lwRREEkG2YwwA0qpDGS3FN4IJ9UkAG1q6ECLkqGa@Ha3jpm6i5Loh4ZVANTttvK4tbR51/VcvXKB9bLWv/1u9nUlUCc/Jm6XvTlDAuDlK@RsOLeBfAe@yaZvDiUeYKRXgZbTDxc8vpAPZqcyFA1Q0hjrtsPmw2OZEkJYESNQhePgmaq53Cra4/04hHBWpekiYsOADsoJpFCTx8aGFhTBJq3usqiMuAbJ9TjgBUgQdRmZnC9eC7qwbR7FmqVwiiLQ/aekTgDPFUv5MDGEdlFRWa9yuPwkM9y/KxVdsdqDujUwUVeyxcqVJzFRmWjSiYQmF3UEFh7dTrM59TT4epuHQbnAqmnp8PPcvmvAeuuB7EeZrHl7T7fuVrUqrn3731jxGT5OlnmZ8OATSxeHe4f7h6fbJ28OIZauA5Z2x4/IRryGqQiOvTdcbukexHwgqPkT@A/kW3MBlHDbyolxY/nUlCBa1mVF7kxxpomYt8RfVZ834r53wwgeFrbZlLUMwAVGERsiDUsPNewyERcoTSPqMzG/gMbUIQYPIE3g5cSqmRWAWSpgKx7oorNL@wmd7sPxu6EcjvaNmcGQYxF6dUif17EmSi4/nspd9/w/V@93BzK7eWmMLeUG4JGrmGcva39py@OdiejhZ08cd3KekGcS@fMGVsaH2@HWgJJHYyIiBtPKjKTKQK3is6MKx@2gksLiiWYo9njkYlCKf@yNCZMwEwFdWDXhRSiKJQDlG9QEJk@Ng@D4VgWwz46Bu6KFzFiAntyBDrMuCYLyAnS5azhExYDoQp0hU3vkJi44NdJPy7@ZMIWh0XDPnrg8zY3p6uKeh2fwX@sVwpN@TobMtGd6XWmsjz8upZzBgUOw6bKvI9iixwR8iLPuxzlF/XvQp5abwxaoaUBqjhuDr101@j7oTCYYM/dwCqxtwOXVNqEzCSSL0j1s8FVZlPVciXQpCoHxnEw@g37LYK3v3dcQemMi2bE3@M0N3Cwo4JAXHO1UDoReKjlnWsD4CpkOcpdodw07CppQtMXygwjKcFnF7Zvw6COKqGNMk4XOCWWRhQcNaCTMiO21fVBJmlB9w0SSoBdLQgnGp1R5geVVYfJCaBJLRIZM0yWMKxfuansErrSSxxlvuaRFykcQfZjMJMbC6oKmDuznVDdeQn1n9NcXokF3gD3FFeTN6KEWSiRSe0EvW4s4Aw9vqdW9uNv/g7X3XsagPmHwjzMPQbbrwtbG8y/EfroOtj@WWTLg@1H3PYqi1V2U7/pOJ@Rtpa5p7qBOB/JNwqGjCFU/E4Fiqocq/ur/UPmm6jsFyu0ZwxjdYVsJhynMLsHlHFBFY3BeQrjehzDUWpfAZ0AcQGRoIyDYg2lZ3l1BVVdlrJZzDgu3Gq0udsa8j1VpPny7QBVOIMkli0Wiit6FjKpXoQASR/VGR5Q5QBTqRIwRunC7ldeN022sbHBZN80ulalWOYEkl00Xi3Lr6OMLkJYiY8WagziQJRxDPCrimjKopHWUxgVe7OknkTG1nI5vYFIqJABgqTQ2Qk12IDM6QpUATE7MIYlsWkUjoKAaztuTLlyCEgFQBw2V0s82SbHh05xYSHWSrV4NcgvMdgxBivJsyi29oqdBqdOXSicZkB9P5tBvw6Y/8kMLdScslBD101tycq0rmMsDXt07Li4RrMHuWVKPptfzurFVIxCZQEK8ovt/T2AhBYOHMO07Ddu39/a3t3/4uDw@IbiOAqZnA6WZMnqRvpU1TK1emRIRvmeROrjvezxs8d7ISrjuRpPQmCI8Y766WzOSm06p3NSf8nP995MmzxuJKTn7guYtquqe3Qo5Sb0sW82FnCbHy@8kaqSurqu1Teqp07iRvLvZ6k2T2hLSFxgOvVJsXlyOpuYxegqkxO8ysTXQrUVOuqswCPNgXs@1oAhHGIePHgIBTiApGXDUPOYJ2TggM8AjVU15fldKj6xPj5LRPqpoxzFQp6Et65g0xprFhUqNTuG3@naTQk68Bbq2OUKsUKNT5EqLc3vd@1ASUlCCyuIEqgBVdy9MiwNNdrtoaSwmROsDLtNS2cILyVBIwB4ycOB32GHbj82t7VjhaYjkEbYzoCv/Fvsi0EPwrXpc2TRDCnIJypEBkQlo6zyUTW0LKGkc5hGRaiQXg1VdYqCa71WQRmmtI41bNlnwMCVVAZa@mc6iFWRGhEsNCnudJLA4ziGP8cTmnGUfpKu1uEYuFEzNNtpWUMFlY@V6iCfonvy8uVFMiXfoAFSGLsdqpic0hwbNkQjEC1irHV1qrGtRxeuTGngXV9HBW493EhcYZDiceA9BSP0T0q7Z/SZMiB9zj7TGFmVU8XJ@IGXYmqVa0VyWDpNo2r4kAdIzRi0TSYiHKbgPKSSrUDtoKvvtPDzzu6zmq5pdTBTIim2iDNq29CV41xUSoJREkQpEdgK1i0rYY449Wqc8iAO@kukY5GhUuMZ3qSJlyb/XcQFlZpVH8Z0041bIMfq@npJ1MYkq1lnQBY3ubyWBbAzWEgopQJ@hZoLwBreu4EXtOACI7CFR19ajmMBgoBmegb0wcYAiMxLZcLLljLjexoohQTP4hOhNwMyOnl/w27yqov7TxazZZqcKV9Dn/r6FDvVtuhWR9n/Matly1fKYrcyyoKgk6oqi52Knl5eSqcXnSVl0cGu/uFDnNO5XgRJoqHBEGkIgdTFbqoM9AySR2XRKS8aG8piq5JfohhghUHaFUT44Ge1q0XjOrv4EHrqDLh4vPEqiz4pzc1pmn4N@cMWspjNAM1coY5RumkJk1@002nMg7bYwAx8yJ4ep4lnnx5nafqoLKTR7FlPNLcprhrVxI17pjgChbOoaGDseWTs4vhRIwyMaojCtecZfnNkD57wl7hywWj10/Lj4r886XN/xiL4XZL0GXIVxVxrMSBwqAAS0ZoxUilgJr/4RUIvMllZ3Cwudy/SyUKuDC@9XGAF9tniqarmF2sJlni0WDeMoAED9@zS1enO2tkFs9r54tua3dberlUOM@f1w8OvPzQ@vBqOUqdKMrF98F7WVyD8Klun332fVZaf89xT419iKSslskv6w9Vs9vXr1yD04lOratUwiFb/8CFVU5P1mrIKpYomPaqrq0uZ4tpS5uhRspFS8vnUMbNtO8tO@36rBb@y26nT3WfpBH9YWlEZGRIJtcbdNjd7wzYahlvW2dlg1xhxdzsxwM9eIOI@@87Lly/R8JIe9u5IwExwiEyEKzWMQoLlc/m//NOF68zVYWPjL7/Xy1oL@DnAzw@vn6H5WC98trDw2ePHKysZwBY3H37n8NtbW1srO5nCYa2wuaLmFjb@4s8XFvL5jXx2oe77ej1ZO/9azudWZO0vfz/ZODz8lu9jheGzzHQw4nsNfjorFNg5ewfPeZvhP5nftWJmA83N9jvsIEFYrhCzSSYLy8njV0msnXcJXdcTI/prJBDtC0yvbq7@tx8fvE0EiWo@@9KDb5B4myiuJbgRDGBbDm0XiWpiA4MVrxOjbKVSAePqf/u3EL/6BcBBn9EGvKqFEFZxlKiqFYryPlEtgkHP5yHd//u736Waf1SDR15ZzcubdXiW8NmQEtUh@FWr@3ssX80vCfLR1x7qD2P05gQdEEBOE/raysEjstrWo4N8Ib@BZsfCu6SsIKvr@VNOnvDoomoRFTq@uQPrgBnqmrmJKOiYFoQLkMfLBNENEA7RDjcLByIn7vByOtzLU8NYWk2v5B855ZfiiQz/cM8RXtlXXHj0eieb3aiCDIBPqfTotCFQmGWra7LrPpIjpJbZU/oO3bKquhAcfqfcRcVnmAgbIGGFhYiKPiHiJtzGNj6DNQ7zqeF28fmrf/9XP/mrH9PfT@j3n6VEuG9MrV3Uq@EDNCRXPfnqVFidZ@wZfxwH/uEXWtEFHcDkRDOXieipVvFF/8JGJvpOuQmfamShEOMoc8NRgiFSE1LiQzbLsB2wi7A4jxZKC2ulYimfbYQFpILwvJPhWax84xKGJdqEZwH@6B@eyIrvBXIRzhTk5rPAqvd5ZvYPUqKWqNXrvGlX43V013OkIelpZG5M9jkXUkIFRpZOHwGtMkHi8Jym73xepDWtIcxZLQ43ISX@AZ6qxBJX8NQ/LNU@LIUp16rCsKHWq2mRIfhojUf1tHp9XdNepctl8Q/SYjmy4QMfBj8oSP1aVTdeAbDaJNjkipssuo8QOgdOb63xagPApzdqGxV3m34a0ZRaf1WtbUyCEJl79CiN9fAIAFQX6ywFoqiqLtTmlgEA1hUGwxmo4@uN6@p1beP6emMD/jfofS2@4Hq9ceOfPuNnTpixfx2p6rSWrZ5mRWuv1sGuZavoomVPwVCFL4SDLkdKXCFBslpdxeFVRa3pxUKdJAopsQSMMVvSl/LL2cLws@JuHriLj8HzspxdQsN77KNBtFqXEjheWefDlnVyeP3xm/8Tf6cfv/nXYIW84V2l5Nt8i39P3@Hf2wD/Tkz8O3qLf@zkHf4dBfj3rIl/hz7@nbzFv60m/p308E9KVBgDyXFxM9fNXeT0c/0cDDbLgeDeyXX0FnRsLGex3Cg3Yrmeq7fAZMFfDkx2rs1yZyzn5BxdB08wBCwXoKkNnzP4awMUD/7sXA6B5y4YpNLF7pJ0t9P3fYOlTqUaS762QNjTdC2nFe1GHfVA1ZL1ciJ7eprlMjDLr5RJh9T1NWs0dp/vNBpZbGGnz9yD8f/BQS9uvfW/d@A@O3B7LvwfHBw8OwVOWU0/SquP4KlU0xvis5moljdPSypSZEj8iezG5ml1WUVzMQ30nEe39Cc@Y4jwrS6cSslL6G8vy9Stly8vypdlMkRWbmiIACIYN0CsshAHwAXinb7MUvd9Cc8FwSUbGi/BMzRxQ/bl5SkKsTBsif4BHXHr38O//f@t/2cvmFKrp6ANXF1vKPSk8C@Vurq@uhbvakpRhEXZgD90ADtGubquopECXYGppqTqqetr7gZvJbXBAVYxjY0qRR4HBN6RiNKkdPlL@fv9Ytr8OU2WGYMBvSJWI09Ph7lcqtwEl2hJwnhPC1upMm35WWziYiQMYvUUhSislMv6EjfnV/Ll8oqwrK6Vy2vCvKgo6zefam5TL4LQsbKSSpXLOREWhqvl0AggLN8wy9jGy4kUZpY3fCWHk6J0SU9SLskPHyriTqvNfj/18KG@nnv/PnJqNFq212ig@/L793JDxt1BlfUC2HNr798Dz0mmXE957vJ1aUXV2Wf5KqWw7npQqlXwZno2P06zY/hGEHjKO7ufkXFvtC@nSLF@Lud6p8mf/@h73ztNVnC/CLmu6AgAU2GFjY3iSrVaXAFzcQ0KLi/yDUjKWXpdT10vZmVeXCYvJhPCS19bTZHrdRL9WWKDbVahofr4sKvrBNUfWymklObISl2BS@imr69zR7ZSVNbS6@KvspBi1SUm/nCwtJxeWVpdeoSjpeHsB1lr@cqoJLPZ5HXlyijhFNp12RTXuOAxRuPhw@V1QOlarnwqNRo7WydbDbzPFjcIQK/I0JH4tISLv30vWaP5zsJ6vYbFq58mk6XyI6p8fa3AEsmyCKcmgeWztXXO7xO@L9ltPNA8JLBTv6VEn@mry9DfQncr9Wmz1mqOtXC922Nuu70AjlCFrIlbE3yr2w3vvrl0vW7r0m5ZC1Li8OnW9u5JJr8BvXd@b2s7kz9@8Tiho7UwtpP3MtqPdrd2Dl5AhMOnu1vHu5/vf7X74hDcfemN986wLMMaWFbjcjC4fMve2HbDBux1B7Ztu6YHmWhYltWHYOFTtixmmbZvvHljeH16GGfaH3/2g48/@58@/t6PPv7eDz7@3k9@/s1PfgC/P4Tfj/j3R/9mvYDvn3/zz/7g4@/@Hjj@Z/j9J/j96c@/@e3v8h/Z/wx@/yXm9mfiFwvHfxLA@vWff/Pj3//5N7/xU/j9C/H76c3fb/7p7N9Pvj//h/F@/Ae3h/nRv4XfH3FYYdgf/S53w@@N8L/Lw/3GTz/@1r/j/38h/tD4ex9/68/wJSz/9Kd/8V8@fu8/5PNrf/GvPv7gRx@//@OP3//ex@//8OP3/3H@42//Kz0Xf/3Bx5/88X//kz/673/yv9D/H9L7j@7z//Gn//Sv/6@//o9//Sfi96fw@3dg@tO//g9Aun/7xz/D/x//8d/@p5/h///xL//2j//Xv/31/50Mv8MN/8@/@Df8/Tff@8HffP@f/833vpnz/sGt72/u4f7NP4DL/fN5Hzj3KdenunzzS@XnV8HGOBWgAbqYhuVBtH08slhZyrEc4y9ogz/5Jx9/@9eAtH8LAoLtfwYb/HMLeP2QLOzrr5Hvxf1ZmiZZ1PTXX6O/GI5@DbZElebGsAdYy6@ll0DaXVpfj82ZRWB@CDHeZ0FGzz16DyC@pvj8YV@HwSBv/xsFg3BMBAvDTWaSwuAOVO7@82/@@e@TRxQXnX9tAmQudI6HXsTg70N0/BDb/bi48dA/RNbx8Wff/fj7//jjz37n489@HfsKdWU9s5WBHv/2GWgIWLhHOAxYvE84CKjj6JItsAUpD4aFDZw3lfT069eQ@wUwwUBsSSosg03Sq2TW0QwR02DjM2fDNL7hX1pZZ2gBlyG5wpelwetxmlUqlbQ0rIAfBQUrxhmy6ho4DXFmowJwMRKPk2mswRiHDR8TFIhZSR@xxlJlyCOm0aFKEJCuJHQ6kvW8nF6r7ECCleEOQ1gIPC29hu/rSnWtMqwiuA@UBYCRfgxJQqgK5m5Y/QD2CsGE8NJw5wNkZa2STlfXwKWChUxTapkGpakXqHBU9jSjcqM7Y7gTdPMRY5/J@prMZ14AlUyExnd6HBoDQnDwP00vieLQf2ik3xLGh3oaEn64G/ffRGeKLwIAXFXFDYTwU1XMzSPwHnJQaUoWPmkOATCXJrEqBAkOJMCkpTTVb5oskD7k4ZMfALlRlXiBFhcXJbTKy3LjAAaXMIrzzkt@YHi4xEkSZonJxXUZnXE/VlhA3La3eEhj0aWdJXjr8L@7QHusqUzlJWkxifMcSSZS/SzNf48eLbHPAAf0HbtJTE0vuytughd3I52W85Bw1QXbEhU1TYBwHoL@09KrhMQSRAPQaDL8DR@tQu6xJkUOrypSemzHWU8RQ9MyWiYjvhp9yUETBo18xVdbJEmSj4qYXlyhkzZ0K2CKpaieTAsFMiY9888eu0MYkGRkOaMXcVUsJaZ1Tkp5bLPSbikH72@7pVLlg76yKsGX7AO8oFBclQfU07E8S9vYQOjVK5Umn9AIkmxRqlbF3gCmS9Xj3RMIfnLA9HxOYzCYuVpZza8UVgr55WKxsJrXV4rrK8XC2jLw12KukM/r6ysr62vrq9ezONEj4FaZ0lKzsFH9Rzee/@EfzXpmu@IjVb9mQw2n@9Vrqdqt8O2qi7hlQD7NyWWaEyOsLtZyGfzLLy/DG7Kc0Qur9YWF7pWKGDilPZJXuCkDci1dqQzGfg/gYdIDiT0AJ3ggDVw0ZWKby/5BWWxpwPuW@bYGWS8AXUOVnAJhc3DS///8/T4JdnV1FftJiYXvfCdg1SqM9NT9PSkBTK7Dwk0Rqt3SOhpdpNwaeBb5njG2s//V/vH@wXNtZ/8YRl7fxvNompS4vr5uRwt2ZLXYwcGBhL0LDKyXdYx/bbLBYEC@TbBfDw2pH3/KE7a@lM@r@WV1WVf1Zfy/w5DH//uHz8N/Ht8Qazkv8ZPTXTzDFc5ZriP/lDa4WqAqXhvqGq1KdLU2U1JXrUrLNelsVrldqdU1PFBdbmlNtzXS/GAEo@2W7fe7xqiSbHZd8zwZetp43xgeeqxkjazWaACeAxeG4DRo38yvFkoLWS@r4b51pc1Sm/niKricOqETuBTQ5dWk03qppYU5egaNCOLlS/li4XpDaA2sQnkwX1XMxZXIXMlxHesa9yqXjDag4crke3xKcr6wJpdr5bF9tSiX69ePelbLNthpDo/GXc2MWCzK12E4SBoH8DjFwpQe3hGEm@BLudNcak7kHESGLFNOpQ2hiqhKuzZqwCXreFNqrb4RKimqSh8@fBjSRqnSvhOIHVP5lTV0ZxLOGDwEyeuhzo2F4tiYQ@MJKpR6DnUHvN1hT/HgQ@CyE5dvsH9smXNCbHcMujh223N9/1cI89hwzrnXjs0V2UReTwzUj@/37KAzJ8SLfg8Pw1vePxiE3V4TMog0xQM8hpfXdd1ZAVbZi8M5pXwWKaLDzVWkiQ6CH@1//uQk9j3Z3dp@IhXZ44PnO1OfgghUYE93904i6yr3DaMWIhDf3n36dNoqPiA2lGlua4EVVnFzdWgBQcAIDDnTkGtsWC8nADPBNcjZa@WWM9jUHz7UD5/iAYYiWwHJfHk1VyotZhk0hfI1FK3y@LzUx@3avtVf8qu7w0MP25i/vgJFZgP2AirhsuxZQBOJNWiosnwN7XNvazubrCRbKPGGc3jPcHP3us5PKtq@RAeG8Y5SvI84kFDlTcu9dOgQZrM7sNigz@Y6wged0OjZZ52ABZduGEBqGgaD36c@EN@KP8HtDgFPg9xu@HRnBMe9RHab5SSNuHF@fa2wtr6cX8usra@tFPRioZDR8xl9dW11HeSSnL6mF9cK63pmbWV9eQXkKPAtrK9KCZAn7HY2C6KqLsvwLQFYx8R7tjbwwjJX61SlBJ@CZu8UI8USRmQfMNmCODJe8OoHdH5lya7I@RU8XLasM4BoMJMl9va2c3t7svwYLbhAtp2T5RZaCmu53OpjWbbIZxtkvbwsuzzOGh7clwNuyeUeb8vygANAhXmy3EHLbhHH07Jso2V7a28P02mjJY/xIdg59@GWbmhZhWAOWpaXaUAuy28jcBBuiye0QjndRQumiT573Gcb/GT58zA/uRxAOOLhOIQnYVm3tmR5n1u2ttBnmwpe4Fn9Ei1b9MiyBxYgQlk@A8MZdgqy3AQjkqIsm2AyRwa44Z1mqDPNgZYojziCEEWyPKTQhnkuw7BRuGMyT548MTpByzrjz8jjX2hg@@BjDwe7e83PP2@enTW90dbu50fos739xGiPBl7zrCmiNRvwuBAHfM57o@kH8rjfaBjdmT5fgo8z5dMYNSzMW8N4C3kSzxkm0mtsg882@MyawefQ4OlB0CY@j3vwfWw0ySd8yIe@w2ZTLiOhom4DnG/HNnPuAC/I9AzTc8toH1YWWFJJZka1Yq5eJnfWU1jqCngX@rcVuiYbh1ogiV@NasNKrl4ZVlbz4hCcIp8O8wVbziz0NvV1EFGMTT2/kh6W8FoFt51kSVXfVPSHS@@U5yCNLK@U5NPNTVWu6fXNvL5WKq6@WhrIcqqE783l1dI7GI8lYdCFr1Rttb4Jcs84yupq2sjmS6urOFYrXwNGAuiXmoPAajQU5dIyzlMpzDH29iCLUXHZiIpql9vKMDOs8IyxEcQfVvQyV@LDcjeAtVB/3ACvpOUgzxTEwHAzV8J1D0XW19dkyEI2q6RSyJiQlcD39ctwcTb6xAwTRv5orKTyG631tWJKw1NVDbfdoFs92et4yPHOBuklHoQkJQjhfmWaE/BL0gmORbFHIBnLbgKX4SqohtKQq4lifJpSX12XpKoYfx3yawbLwvr5k20NhmTChhrptD2UcV1P20a2N@HDtaWFTifQ1WlPLNyFbIZu21w9gbY7hKE3CsqhR6hZSBMqYLSTJ@UrtYFrJd86OT85@Vq9joM9hrEozwge4yqTvh9UiID6@@wWMypVMBkoUVIuAQWpS0JHo1qtNCo9q9cPRlDmMN6XjNTbjQHt@7ww0fEyin6FRy6FR6OSux6Hfz7oscc8EJ3LDKM1Ko8Bv7myg@pwLbQusmFiKFVbqNzvceXx1aCEUul12apYnud6cgIPs246lYHjG23r0PLwHOX@wSJrMwtPLJqd16e7GHIbxetrteoxZyIfiqFWm6lJp5gVUad8K8LIFZ0EwOW9axilKK9S5bdg8xaZ0tIepzZXyi3lMWukwCX3uv26zfKsuFKmG2QUhAQcgTCHGDFSleqXAJjDPS@VICOCJM4BJia0CDVit8jHSPXt6/JZpYah3@NrQ5XluqrW3telalmqAoMpjxJGxR80@dXQuaaezxXLQ3DTV1fKHdasNF8Ny16lD0NQVu5CtYupCn68wcCt7oAkgPPuvfLx177LUhtqocIdywTsfReEiYbWqAzHNbRcqeVXipl8cQVnNorL8NMz@eU87t7N5HPrmbwOMgXIGhAffqtgX4EfhAGRI6/j/IfSVWTG5ExumNP0jG7pGSX32m69TmXOcQ4KxEJCWioTuLsOUA44IAEB2ZIVvkYqnV/qKi2XGRsq0TAwvTIV1Mh0WN/OdBDMkWV0efCUypaXlO6igmEWTwb93Vq9VNod9r@FXor6drOYXs2l36VSZWWBpSq@9ZawjPyRsNBfAIoW0zrMH/RquQUoN7RB9RpqO1jUV/Ol2mCxpupQwNz7sw25Ktehuq6ZBH/x9WMQu8rgFvJBLqiNRa2xWx@l7K4FVauv58siiNQXjFmRlVM5PI2jJJOr@WQylSzj3OYCuAvGTiw4Cb1C8qG@KYOoJ5fk9Tz4j9n5jRzwMXxRlxLXEkrgDEbziSvp@up6I7458Us2GhlpNbQ@ZOwsvSixLG3v0RoJtkAmVavSHPRWZevsaKssQm9tS4kSbaIdb3Fkp0KdAlOzC5@6qSi9UX3Fv6e4oQ6SlUhPVI3VaY@AZZPq3K/wdNkmS0K5DK9Xy@eX67X8KnTpwIfDoPk8FN2/kji@@Sa07Ea6yrKnkiwTB@JbFtYKKV4K9iFBbZ5tX4VTHCW6woApRom38Vo99eG53b1aW1b5WFxhiQ8sndVoc2Yj@yEBfeR1gu/pzk/v6YashHt0v3ydL0BtOW7oAGPxAJg@dLSFgozzstZr1j9ef7X6au3VsxcHLw722KNcaa20NnOR5vRRJlPSkxs4qnu/4OIY7oPzxbdYmZUT/eTySnLO4s5pJTGsrISYYHq1quobebYJ5M1K0C209aKae1/ltFolj2IefD7@2k9XhhtrYM@DZF0CZBfS@WpVX6KDEqlE/@M3/xpP617tfrX1lCVRd8rf/fnv51f/7s//Je0OSV6X0S2/vJqAkGjUi6uJq6v@1dU1PNyvkKgnxCaaldUUWPjWHT1RzSbEbpNVPZXwVRFKXy0k/PdCm5KSz62B3/YBt8lFwGpi98gu5PVHG1g7elQ7LPrbsPz1hJRYe/b6PWNgMautszM7T6Zsdhp5pQ/qBvwvfsAp8A/qAntdqbLFLE7mr2PocFpxqVqtLuGCG0tW03g0PU9qK6q163I9zWiiDwd8Sw79Wf4S/kX2V9aS74M99LaW3vhLE/nYsFihCjW@lM1mT1Mff@238/ni3/35b75vvG98Dex8fX29qOcTv4As3XJ0NBzw0cQRHgJFQzRQZHPuy9VMWUrgJcptxsOHw0YcKKLiBK52Cm3ShWsL3UINwKcBUrpCwZbwAFyG5HU6LZ8qS1Ik1JI87p2ZGYLBllBFODRC6Up6gF7QFbIKsD/pwRgUOPRQX5XZ8LsDr0@ipULx9HqGPYQokMID1HCyQAf3BA9V9TLLLt2MyrPMlR2R8MJ6lu@jkjNg8dIDiPIUKJouLGN9Aw9/YkjbAZ6tYRDKJ3m0apB2HdLu8ggNclWo9DxAhvHc8UgOyOvSAzzJRgI99PDM3oAAZZaSHgACoAyKAGzX2QZbTrErO50uj3WiXeM@SFSIYYRHyySMhtBaeJ4yjFzGcDbXezLwUBcYEzVsWnHHEAiHwdflKjDUwOhkQwmJTo/eGxTAIi0CChWNPXw4zlWlYrdSjEqE8FElHOpxGyuwupEAAAvHaZ@1SnKGOek0VvaDSbIDjKcpu0B1KhnGgdp4xg@t15IE//cmWqTIqaoijzIWQNQXbxUmoAwiI9p5HZqo1E7Pr6ZYlHkT8m5Spkg3TjT4PB1@ppGKKpNn8Vr6RSJUpwv85SQ@RBJ0O322kEEPN0BFp6g4gTMDcWqQ38uEfGo/CGNHsaAodpdCt20PBhu0xBhq2VGW9RRGa0culA9i3fkVhlsTCyn8UCwMjbpYDNRrItJZoLlxUgjn912HFKHQoXLcwEnq6XyJq33h2R44lwapNOOp0H7HWI64njikfFJj5nBdbT6Pi2uZXBG/wE2GWWcaafzJrzOF6x7EKUwnApeiSJRhGGIaiONm1@pBlo4ti6EyDr@UzZ6BdDJokvaNZzbQVWfPhu7D8bPiprjspX1uZ09Ql6fqtkHiFac9EyjQ2JEiLKHigvTYde1zi498lYnjuj7LFzMgUWYAs@MfILaEIgAeyc2Bd4aHgt8qfFa5cS0Ti7ugjFI3v8v6gtLAGn3PVUp5eBvcheHE8EvPe0mMV/2RH57Fp8OhYNcilgstkx/IS@KJvOikqCSUBlToQLuGM@59BeSy8AgpGkGKtS4ghKpL2McA0zTDs63YiqG0D6gDoLYHLQuV1QReCQ99V1CNm2JC0xMM3mGfseW8REr9SA2C0FoAMLDqK5PQwQ@iYjn8oAUVo/FJC@Ar0Dp7LfBLoO4mTn4YP6RuNJPipjF5swUBDjsdSqvCeLMILYWYBVsHV8MHRV8AzyLkcEZOFhQ5DWDTckrmoKP409E5tUvES0rsJqQMQwgC1QAFRYXHhs8VeQtNM5eXlxopOxp4tmb5qLzZx1sus/0zGwRYNxtYvb64gsfGm9jELZNjk8pVtuN9qJtDuoZ0/eGIfyWpjcev3w5sz1KSbT@JfeAFqiM@65EmCdTx4BPd7NmkwtxUaF3WF2SWr2euQjIrIZmpa8lrBMIYghlmRhkzA8AyTfM8075slYUHv8AbgENlWaEj6iH0QkvPD012vx2FcAPaSh3am91z0@26KHrIfG52nDQvYRhyFFqFvW8PIZJjXbItzzNGCvmnMDTSqTIi6YaNoHcnHzBCb8KuuLoue1gb1SeiD6Po0HdF67Qe6pGQrm4HyrWkof@Q@w/Bf8j9h@NEw2RrwzqXvNDpGouDxI1qocKQCGYUhrnmSt7GPgQZRGSmcxAYcjThdg0/s0KxQ3xzG9RjJSQMoAnSraigUsfaad3xrculejp7BjQtEyKgxgF0rU44vWxFZsR@96Lbd/0JJwe1JkHnI/KNTmZHUAOnFSxjVEFEGBxfNirXOetpfHqG9/uiwAABxS3wRAlgK1DsVDlSa0ueQDg1eYxjnrGayEydhCzhJdxAKuKo54iNA6rHAKF7VCTIJviwsOUIhfyCCbz08FbkMKxKCvZJP2@yngRMTjUVzlLKVEmxXKlqmE1AO0qllemihP5QFbUpr1gxr0X9x7O/8MnZb0O7mJ17IljeL5SleFOxhqiL1BLNhbDKqpVYvUIOsktG1/Kgg9rlYqjolCGZpWw4muDpYBG4Dl0lVvlmitcPnVKRHbkUkcKoUoEijiq8WfJ2EaKUIzyK5otoo5AQRHzOQABGbmY0S0QbxqMNKxXOONhwTrTLWCaHlMkhj8JDD@dksi6iwSAp0tKK1VNH5XwgUMkAT@e9JSqilZlvXKC2YfYGlenA4ClMc8xziAoEDaEkjXRm1memXotlOsa0pgAgId4A0OJ3AJWkaYanq5Et4lEclSGP4jZBBpxXAIERCy5zhWlKRGQ01AW5Xk5TPwBtV07XJFnHfWb0l@M/ORM6hj/9pmNuMqQ@6ZjLTP39gzjWEbOxBhoTMvTcCjJkHLBskf4YEEsuXabMEJ7BPRveH51tdt1mtmfg5gy8Yz66VToVjgdIQ@SjvhsYgbuyUuKDIJvo64UIzmK3cPAxgH3muDDUiCtktLkCSSeJejJN98yxfSuD91hzEdyiDQT8ZhMpLvcKo@tLkpg@5MNSBM0JCEXXRgNvLms0FN/qtlOlSNspWjWkw2RSwvEsmGLxgQ8JoAd9xW2@scwgdTdM1FYqop3Y5rly0BeeSUhkiwGzMkGeB98OiCrMd8cjQVIjiKJxM1DompWO23PPQLxDFaEYewr8/hg2Zsjo9ykvGWbgELUU0@lKzUExM0ZKRP3yk6OyL/OKkYri5ycBTCAjw7xpHCNmvRnJNeYmx6OF6R1/en6P4/k9vj2/NKqezjMfale456clvayMIUDAcTaW785GRmjkvpGdiaxEzihA8Qj3zmKLNj@1MKdbEHRLBNfaQB@ZyOaTniCR8a/m4f/2Cgyj7963@gy8yPF4BPymh3vsFLrZyA9XFhUIvp9C3nMzuYi0d@6ZFoTFyzT2UFYAeZUYl4NKqKBh9mEY7UdKSULAd9A87my6Qfe03anCPWfkybvIsPP8/CraabSsrjGyWooImYnBDUt8BCMz4lf3KzgyOmJ6Lh/UKdBJpeIarBHpPFBpDskYmYuY/vIbYXgQO6IemvmmHO7Pxx/632DNOGVX4bPPIPAnkwlSdU83E/RH/RFX3tklHcAhH@X9D69JPKt7N0IAD2JTRGacbOo29nmkREW6R48QhdUmi0xqusJuy@31b9bhp6Ho7pJC5cYiVcJanlAvPq/G7dtqPEYVIU3ypZ/7keRdRHdvmouRGgc2ZmHbn9aF3ICMmyFMU4lD5C631pjr3OAJ6Ebzbs6cXqUxg6FGMYnTBTaNq0m@SEk4BN6HL04gfQVfBHhmBQ1OUGHZcI5K3BTHyKdn9GNSi3ABaRygxLAYXiJB2YiFkkIzBL@6jtI056Zp3kjTnEgzagGTScYCSeZEkqIWsHpuq4Ku1Q7mcGf0wkEyfG5j2/A4ruHhtMRV0k6W7AxLXiRLwJCTVrK0qwBTTraSpR0y@MnSMRnOk6UvwTBuW8n3yVLYLDCAB1YyPEJ3wcLRbiZL20rqWgrwno8wXS1ZiuoUwmxyK2EEUIHlBqkRl8wcVxQz8Czo2EiozDCkGD@D4ySacMnQLwf/XKE/v3gGPHHOcokCszTTJzqNWI/B04FuI1T1OqMll0RvvnuwR5uJxjcmgH8aBnPxOAQexPBEcpIZ8YyhL61QwBcyiHyzNDtHTJ@8VuMe2RGpA4VSJU@mT9jTSB5oKeRfg8D11ORtDSJ@WF@TIHgF3i@fGHlePm9kJ0yOcoRrrKkZ2UKkvk7eUiis66mrSHjtx2uI5q4nA@E9p2EQXksENsbTQYajxTZMrO/2J4mEfHGLoB2PQ7NvvFEi9U5FI64gWuYcb3IWJUPGEG/8qduKE4uHWZtgQehZy9V5K4v6BeLF6DXmdTFJlTc@yEKM50ALt8xzC8l2RxgpHGc3Geor5nVDYVyeJHGuSTYJkTVUOjIwAp56NHjdRVUknzZ8DWMOcVJFQQCxmFEqnL@6nyC/u1x@DwXqEAlTCcwSrGd3pTfF61t72amcd8fJ3qxA9MywndRM4ShKYYxyGB3EJPPbaO2GiI9bOLiQzxONoE9J@yHaojHBHXibHltwWCgleBeTjud5cDzPz0fUTYmke6GFQouGKQk4vOBRTsdFuz2vvOCzqhh9aCLb6H5yBXuTFRyvPIRHBfCmUM5bOZ4MxbWtcdsmPbrogixVLzHOyGn5M6rmsSOwe1qKjZZhweGgcbRz8Pzpt6HTXV1dTYk@ejTOH7ZanFSN@nEOmTYyR/3BjGFLPoN65HHxmu7lxTuDF04d@QYv4cwahAG8PyckP9HGU4KXxfj5VNuFeDxsDKMC1vm4GRgTXAlFHQO7bFvgNQCEWIGyZAggoXgL@M7QaC2Fc7JAHXgVX6NB3VejgZuRGg3Ri2HVhCvcqV8kFrID36MLWLmW60tJogPdbOeAvXyydcJOnuyyvRfbX7JvH7xgL7een@CR6MMXj5/ubzP47T4/3mXjGQV88OYPHFACXncs0@o1gWXnc7kVRpC33f6I8x1lO8Xdj40ee@KaFq5HbfhG71GHWzTHCqo81i4MR0c4h2nT5TI9Owj4rXkmgCPhpkXH3vBEAIOwTRjT9nDM23NbdtuGsBKOffu25YdnsljXhhoEfhueuMxwIQlvIaGtQHQDHV0eiLfPQXhcpAEwhj@@7dD2eQSrpTGBuOj5ZAye7B49O2Zbz3fY9sHznf2T/YPnx2zv4Aish9/ef/454HP/@ORo//EL9KKAzw529vf2t7fIgWcgpzE89E7XCd6WBQ2DE1bMc1zipmuYI1t81hmCgQTPLg06AOiz5MBB7mMbXfud1UqWJbyfiB86pDUBFt0OyKy3uJQZrvnSfgL5hU837Czm2AalBo2lCu2tLJordHuo6xwXHnojhjctWWU6gK6QeXyDE23KadkWk7dxzwnOffNz6tSWQ9CQ0ALARlDhBpQKo4sDksnMBoGsQmpm10W1azw1vilQWDDqo3DrSFkijIm9LwgUjwnsOzgfpJcjB6B7cMiLZAOPB2DLkQMPwFa4A4qi@7gXhBVEiEFwMED2zIrc4U2vv0frv2w1cnhs0Ch2TeSJ1xtVqcHGl7rbvX6Xrn7gszx0o5Phm7ZNUXwKj1cndLvhtYpNC0geeKK4BAv3qkFIGZhNG5caxDY2Z0ANG3yBGnDfj9EOfKZUUho7wc0@lmPzOzXOuobDtzSNt@IQ7bE1VEtSERu67eiyCjp40XeJAPECmcl8RPF2hFRo3TcexHx8I0VD7HmkC4/CLWV3ZeDxjQz8MmAAkDox0jGpp6LTnwjGbQtSVnwXKBLnbT/EwwM5twamNREhvPTyjf3uXUogOTMxTgr3HVLuoIrwftAMX7Nsux60cWKrPTzGglzQ7Lj9wOZ1qEyWYHxlGYTGjg1Se12pTqRG15ROpei4TizRJlDxnFSbQJT3SZUoni@SR@wrbOvRnWm0jw6zYzTx5uHx2lkGF5EuLZx@AUGY3/eIvQ3d3yvkT2nMOz7QHZxrlerO41P1w@sM3vjA2QK/5SzcRMjv7OxhWtA8aJ2PNiB6KHeJlhZeG@IPmhhb7KkT3BJbeQgMxoEdG8Z1jxrlyI9vH77pjudTpt3J8f37Co@lImfiHHngd5Qxd8uwWphkhuLUmdjrEeOdkFng9UrokiGYEb9@hEdRsBbKgBEH@Qjdtjt5XYdgIWHpmoM2cBZxIZeo7gh@ilVp60QoSNKjxOsj@0p5XElXU9nxzhEWQ6cSsuhMCBnv6xrvP6H@6ga4ndvBAf@@P7i1W3PHu4dPgrZzK7RPypuang@Ld0sxWPcH@@EWsLxz@6XAQtkz8wHzTvImtIjSI@LMLCai3bG3p/j6Rt1R2wMw2PfiDEoENJbawKEl6lA3qsIjpOJgxgLR8cnO7tERk/n4BOIC38MhQ0uwQYS9wG8z4btnbYeYnRYJTdFgORKeQpeJrWvhc1tjnom8OaxCyCAZgY@IWUzeHUpcT/QsJELQbnpiiCHmJnN3FfIgvyYAX6MyXGBeibEYFhVQmlnMBO98bD@@qVvgLcNl4/iefNoxzftuvAXMG8UBxTf/GGd4UmR2/b3k8nEpTIcLWNbbARW4BZI0XoSrsWNIuA8BNW2yBm@plrBKcdM8F7ATIe5wh1duUsL@1QmKCIkL4VwWjrF1IRyLrHH5eDEUc2jnIXYDBm7pFJ58hzJ4hCyeXDbiFZoad3rKZBcEQibeT/UoThUQvX5djq60Vcb9ZCUSyONtbZFyUwtzWcfZWQG7PD/QZ7i3uTjNHqaTAm57a1Lq309SvJeYSCnE@czChJ4AuVgoLN8Fe7oUYXT1V4XN@5Bp/hn0@jC@H4P0Rz5N7wPl7j/PhP5jArgFdXyrfNhgpiKCqDOjT5koO3VG8fxBXvi8EGQGFQ2bHbyNazLVFBtO5W02dN4jxaFTkBtliDXhqKC81dzA/vXtySFDvjO9hU9Pjzc2DIR7BK9/ER2ui6lhiTnhedNJN8vzHArGjyX1XDw@RqeRbj0zR4fm@IZWXhj0pGW2eAHa4pAR31abCacYKBGaVdTw9j6c1CtPz@qpejlewr39p7tsidTbtSemIGVPTsVYzoLt3JYBYr00HYG9Bh3F@8wvwQ/ykAlBAproUJ5CuEndmTfCCAjLNbrGQWz7FCxVn670tm8aDuoEych08fVDiEiTr7sHe6lZE@q58kR8yJzfdxSIlZFVTaao4IbzuAhpEgSvTXSP9VMS3mMgNkjectevkdXXcsV1iUrnZIJMr7ZezyyZFZlBn2s4PX/gXbbOz9zORZt1Wf9Nc2iO3r1lrLDCliGt/EOuQ1MvVvCUq8JQ4cgaW88RwYoMbpKW0lOZMY20MeJ6MhsPv8sLLEUGGiuX8ATEFJWypV5IhXhSLqj0asV6xankyr2aUy/jWb0gXQnSelpBh4fQeQJr4QvytaCOXekv4rOtlnPBvEFzBKOk6OwHo7Mf2L/jDJfYs03z5bTNWHqAm9XwDInmWJdKdI85UqaE8o/0gA7x6HhsnKaLcbalZUMOAPsZEFb9Ib1HKelBThv0A5d8REIqkhB7b7@XHoSnjnI0YQBBanY9zM4GwRmHUXDdh7uO@G5oVefSmI5HHVMxEDWMSdxOPpVlPAKIGRVHr2p1ydcsw@xgJvDGyvcUjW1s8Kvsr8GbJulwp4bh0cGHXB2NuL4Bnz4tJmASJJj7dHxDguKjXUcDd6EpqIDOu9BGd4kEQfTBbdzsio4jUfwNQABH/AMuUmliBlMIViAn8qN@NHeACukmx/W4ioCnIHmlPMDCImyeXmUMnHZ8E44wWYEmcH9wiejkuIJHlEDVyXajGFH4FA9OKKFlaGHzEZdUpeRVxU93HE2JRVPDaGHgGCoe3IkNnMiC0c8zC5rPiG1b3S5kmuPiwRgdaKTjuCL9dJS@X8M061Hmub96w1@d8Ne4P8/UOJQG/fc4UCkeSE5cjcNdM3kcLHMjrQoj2USDmjY1kDjGYcu3hfW1wG3Y48DVqCo5VUYeGxMeaszn1Yza5z4LE3EiAo/8a9xf0Hde1HyUy4mwjybTx68kKsiivbFiK8kUlWqO3d3knVPkg2QmAzYZ49GxvonseKMURyYFOwEBDafxqdlWK2MoaT3kONRm5OrGI1kTwsSmMp0NfujwRsOa0UZiWKI004S4IZ0vhHTIeyEGgmAiobGw5VbDyCMReRQDi6EWwmT5ocUbDRyKNt3EK3iM8T2@wsY@mbkwXGK25wOe8yEvPD@MPIkgYroL8mw0TXITPPbBHUWhbulFxmmPpiHOZhLPY5O8UZoWPzLdxlnuhYhPxBlFyClu4D3yEZgeB9BD8p1Xheh5Lf0iuyR9boAI3e9aQ7aFowiDTlNJE@fRUUerj3qTSIWLP@j3u7ioSILdJZ14Fmo88gVcTRlDjC2jadI@btzh4TNoEufHIZLGDhDyJe7/GHv4gzO8RxvXbVBdErBWnFCxA03ackZ8vgLazHKenwq32MDni6IwmD@LZ4LXHG89iGm/b5iWJoEs5oOUI/Gitnn7FtPleCwENXdBl1aSpG8NbPN8@3Ncrl3Vc8t6DGUXYrU3py2vjA9KAZJCj3wOxNWCviJJsaVfky/9qggww55iR/8V0KZ1gbc1S1vQY1BAH4RT3/IurJYmSUdWtMaLcJGUceERj027A8/kczcgW@Etz3ja18/w1S6gMPxi/8xXg01aCstIuCY1XkyGqr6wW4jA8EBJ28XFX1qPwFP9HB8YqWcFgJSlFJvMEi0ti7yQ7NLDeSbABqoliS09RGhw3MA2oWZookrqAii@yjFOjN9JH8sJpGd2DTzkq83KAJ5@GWMgzEC4UnRbHiSxJv5JeWCiYOESuhHWTBa4n0ttBZq75dnAfccIplqhaLG8QwWfPNk/ZscHeycvt452GZgPjw6@2t/Z3WGPv01L2LgOTkpj2ZODp8BdosVyvih@AA7y1jHElMlD2nr@bbb79eHR7vExOzhi@88On@4DNAB/tPX8ZH/3/23v2bbTSJJ8Nl@RLmxRJXG3rkaoG0moTa9seXSx2ytpUAEFohsBQyEL7Naes/uwP7AfsJ@yD/sp8yG7ccusLIQs9WW6e@ZMn9NWUZWXyMjIyIjIiMijtKq92dk/2aXDdWhBvTk4Vvu117VjKHZ8kKZedbVEVE8d7KnX1cOdV/Czsl3brx1/oB73asdvsDM8tK@ot5XD49rOyX7lUL09OXx7cFRVOLDEbu1oZ79Se13dzUL/0Keqvqu@OVZHryr7@zMDPXj/pnqoyAfAGuV2FaCsbIOqij3ROHdrh9WdYxxQ9LQDyAMA99Pq6G11p4YP1e@qMJzK4Ye0NHpU/dMJFIKParfyuvINDC7hPoAVmJedk8PqawQaMHF0sn10XDs@Oa6qbw4OdgnXR9XDd7Wd6lFJJfYPjghhJ0fVtMK7qqhraAOwBd/hefvkqEZ4q705hj3j5C26M3gwye8BMQBlBaruEoLRywFHC0g6OPyArSIeaALS6v2rKrw/RJwStiqIBXSY2Dm2i0GHgMRje5jqTfWb/do31Tc7Vfx8gM28rx1VPZiw2hEWqKG/xQcgHej0hEaN8wRw8SMQa0JTbpqmU9X2VGX3XQ0hl9JAAUc1oRZC284rwTms5VzCMpZ0B2gb8K9sA0r77quPAeZ5vGt5mW@LMQmOdg52q7AjSz4pJ/pwArvO@kzmI/sb7DTmI/yMZZhpBY3rTr3bbw8wVtRUYwPHVdhJ43UdHqjn6izxhRtbxI5CFZLJev1dpQ6K7lG97qUfUzMGxkM1xMr9pVKejBFzx6PmjQaely8Z75sxRG0tyDkm@eHh@QKWZOwvsGebfxV4KpdrBVINg/CxYW0iCvlU5BJPSoA1UiwjXl0RdUkWCPrdFXKgiq5uPtusoxkUHR@p0CCEf/o/Rj94c7BeAHdms1Yuh0osgdH9FOhuuBNKbUD/SGaBbpu6zIZB8EPHzdvdoc6f7QwGLdfzdB0qOwY9sON6D1RvBJ2Z6pnZ@gQsnSpLyvlQ690kwpjjZUGZknnJjmhkLv5TH9MfT0PDuRvQKEpdkS1ajJPuAldHh6O0khQVGD1Bk4wy3@vKd7X3qM3li8ulmfevzHteW@gOiJlqYcM7pXrn9OfVOReABUY5NQAlXcl0kctZdbQ7iSl8AwUvsRDl5Ke9@jKgfR1QAoLstd@z@8TdeNSd2NADH/7msPJ6@2RvD1gnQru8vrK2WkqYLFnfpfnvB@yH8qdSkrAh7OMgp9Ena5XsgOBDK8VKuh2RPxFwLocFMa25njR6ifkajFtG3FEJGRkON8R7XProgecEiAdHUSKNpwlNr3NXphCAGxuqh6O58ick4vsgKxENiK9Kb0qzNsF/sG2z/PUSNwMSAhISo6y1QLmgXRDfc/a0JygpN5RnB4tkHU3HnHXN4IBMXeQei8Gz9Eto25rFkD0Vcb3StFNNAOLpLBRKu030eWW/pXwhYuilZF/w5juhN3j8IPnoKDudH44r4yNA456pifboyOgsgz6Vls@3yjBFCwump02F1nxPgKK1J2Zjk@DDWg0Eyjn6DJbVTMMlkw9ktktycP065anPTKmYhAPbKQnFym@g3HnDkVZKOg@I/NbZJRS3ZZKVMNZuTB8JXeSDyUeh0RlD0y/CB7X/O@JkTvuboHFC6xG2rJx9j8Iktcq4AvWVkNK90QcK1ilGhE371YeomVt7Yi7NwOSUZsLhM4ACmZ2pfvGBshS23TkIQCJHw4a9fo3H2aUPqtPXjifV8Tyk37waukr2Cr1V3Gk3s3qeJrErrc9Q8IenPLY1WR3uQ1X1NStuDVr1oDLNqPLqeehwc57O45FbJAOIWfBEpZfslDpLWXlZZZoPSMoka8NpmcxHIJbe3ns6t6isjJYx3i8nXBpR0PQWwnN3nJTlfKDY@zaeIJGzqh9T0jpMtI1qMm4@kmGuQX6WvQDbed4iYwjeNDu@wQ2ix61TZr2oNeU@Jz8Q7CRyKozSAiK79bKAWtpWbwz0ZJlECjXQn/Q5XX3AVi1dIsv5OwRCOxo@q177UwC597hhM4nlFo8GaXRNxM7YLCH18Vbd5mAwAtHRx3EDjOnu1Muq92J0CPrh9UjSDcJ@1h2JRUIL/dANik2svdM2w5nRCbSwO8ZghFaW6IOGdBWgAyhnH5lkVpULxKtpdEsbHbuTpYJyN6Mvm4ATyiJKSNxUq@rHH7kUI1QyfAaEwW5olAtyyaR@8NzBLL@bwegH3PtRBOq3gpZJJGo1SbZAnqRan1IyNsc89OEgJIsGTAVaQAwmCmxIM36osEevCTmJ25ITJbPEVKM0kp/ejyFS7QwFHUWEK70D8a1mYDIRS0XJ5GlyexaKKwTKPIXr9l5ljJJ7xo@nlXPWNyzlJQsR5edadMQn5pvm6QM@iZG//DzE1QNv8CxbRFAEGGVWPD@9y@cIPkzM974bjFq2TRQkmZY/RPMbqT6DPtGiNh1K@r6mPw6DKWgAzVx3kqM26u63g8t@fWfQ8zvdQdcHPQ1TpE@Y4@HjlB5xwjqjwU1IN@vQh5ZVqDWNnjl9DKdTw9/mXLJkpdgKx8HQtd0RxqNp5ZKzQJDlHH38lNmviL6Hs7nOTJ3llahSIh5eSu52Ba90b90XhXmV@eQeGxAGtzXjKcEhomOKO7JiS0t3CjS@VMCCsaEyyvfucciLQbwBKKJjmBjEGpg77gf2IFAzuxfi09Yk3aJcgiPMoxTsBng3TejS67SPN7MCF/kKPQJeqsJ63qrKpygTzCeID9P70V1c@52hBwB@AfiFF/OoZR4hEItr62RKIesrkhQUYCHvvy7xaOLEwMW6HdiFerFG65PZVuOfp/dhgzx8QCiSdHl3qBJXpAuKD17L5taB5dSnHm4qKZXyKC0HiiCVsZu/n2CDh9xjafHjIS5bzpAx7UjLrgX0fahqApbwFs4Z71kbZE6B/PCKKRYfO2szCCzP8yizboBwHS25UIBJl/dXPNYajIAZOzPYE1ePVDgeDFOPxN69vGNuhrV5uG563oN@vkxsZdgsF1uE2vIUH6elxCw8M0QTxxh5lAENofpKz4bMZ5E4KddxvZXr0wfwcB/OIv8os6mY@W7x2sdN8SM67OqNxiwpgh2TjZbM@9M6DLx@PweRNlm9qhPHqCPLqE/50WpqBk0GS4/HEFGfwD6DjxZgDvttAe7s@bkXqbPOcDp1qf4US1aJ@MQ86xiTCXxp2EbnC8wCxxKuYVJG4Jykp3SUV8g0MFkwfuAGUSoOMpEdii240WTN0BEl82@7dfQWKiAngqct28PB5Og3CKMk@mLcEY@H@jRTOC9xSxPTEmgVVOpLLelwcvh5Wp9QK3dQAUt8DirMiO7wpsvHj@qXjgXKQQtcmz6LI28@jYPx1BJAA//Yn@oTlIGjrqRmbEXFF0KdWAOsBdBSOr2A1VWU/rojpnj0bpBlBAoEv3bxz5LUwOzbq3mDbawyaU2xiCfo5tXmqcwWV4kIin8j@mUpsqhLiis0EDDEUL9cgBYwPSlBj4cClFnHprwYoDJHULFcwGUJLym7aeTPOec7IlUKLK9YJfLzSmzYbWTmNgKCxfwyESAgs8wvErUCG91cWKwSa/PHE5UAgVjTPmMcpkJmJY5DM3OMQHgkaA1HOS2odF4omD4ur3ixj4a@6etG3vqan/0K@DEQnmYKs1/X87GvsW6LxXjVWE3Ah2f3GvsIqPBsgA1X@GX/UeSJnbrc@IRaSkZMyhA/7D6qUjeot2W/D9UmxVxrGUO3Zwd@a/WrzjeixJKrfzmRupI0/aVfPljtmKoBkcz@lHVOh7K4rA@SwOrgTo@jQkVX59Ez6Qe0Sjtoq3fHe3uxpK6NqfYzugpGK/l8Hmm4Yeew1y7UaEnqDnLx0rn2da@XG958O3rXyBHrx7vue@HgpVagA5gRWBNhdjDq8D0OCAMUxdIZCVNFVf@63bYvTMADSpw7mDUuKbkOFO0/XePz8u6Y7D/UpOyvFzhAHN@FMovvxmc5U1rRp1BQGz2CPzr68AzQgy/a6IZtDqqoMeTL2pkJti2vvPUZNxC8h4Qmi7IQe58j72TnVdDrDdLq/WDUa2EegCe3sxX29uwKeS6CB4wUu3sdUrbZtAo@dntW1DAWsUkdm9P7kr4VQqd3xxT3h0GnOhm6zumfHdhVYMhLOMwlTDOdVk7H8STn@yOaZToEsB9V@sofuk3C02xh2OllAUdPANGLQnqu6hMr4pFJTHD2cGlE6nxws5SKAYbukSigU9LT9NJI7ilukOucTQptxGGe2xCYMKPK42pgINnvxxU/jtvtxzFFyubPE/ubM0Q6AqAVKMsP8InJsP8lA8t6byZdCMs3eOfGXb6DFepYIZF43iz/5catVCrq2XBpSVUq2/CQyajKdkXt4ovtbbULv7fx90K5uLJSYp67632Gl9v65a3ahjbIwLnUvBztwk/4VsaoMHTWxil@lis/S5ee1cubW6Uwd1rZxqB9ePrrv//nX//jv3IV@fHf@GObfpz@2RTKZrO5Z83PzxZuS/j7dPc89axx@mx4nuqUkMqQ3Z@MQr/nW96j2WbigQipVq/buC9qynjPdENy1UR3SRf@KZdBA/vxR346G0ePo@gRc6JG1f3e8NKn6opa2CqnKqmFBXjaLKf@NUW2E3nvm/ef4L3ykJdT0gRCLd77oypHO7WanXYcuT5J7@0Ac@Tg3ZeSL0cOri6S@o7AzKnKZtV5Rl0Y8NDNo84F4yCymsnA/JsAqUdHPjl0di1qAx5Kk@mbzfF8MHUVdki@06ZzvvzMF03leesln6FRG0vA8LB8iX3VJe4Vhw/g4rFXOXNaWF05zySTyYS5EK3eJDZHvQ2pL3NBlj5Cp/wMHIY1hCUDY6cL6sqIC2gQkZFM0nVZC02@1s3to2pNGhMr3MmUJc@jvYkGkjBsji3cnEwBZSxU@OgKMhVeUxQGygbTx57hAQAUXrdJjEvx5cnhMGh221Pj8oA3UkS9w16JIXOLqn0nYk45o4Yj43rajhoEhKAUQLl6sNHZBhl5AyjbJW7HY9S/Qdy4S1QXkvxbLdMEG4eg4aA37fSgM5dcqcIb4E6AeU8mq9fXoXTYA9dsBCD1BLKiecIiX16EuxGgKaLfxBMyvB@qhzm5WODj41/KRgnrASUcuR@ujaEgbq/PDkSDNjzCho9RdHyERWS4hFuqEBQqtagc6/vlhA8sDj1PDbkkYhV@R4fvRB5kgiR9WC66kzQhfBoz9KQmvt0UShvi1X6oSEtuUE9WkkNrxZy@gVR5hWeVeE4JSMGSWbpLDFjDVF30@hdm/Hy6GeJ1hFlHd8ndFNk/ATiW6UaHy1N3HAvgsHGVbh7DE065P3sQht0GIAuGKNNEKRA5eGAErZ6lEtyZUAseByKC8dXi0Kwoe3yalILJkOLzGd4naNrtayqIFcQDUjwTC/DsDnMcDITlwa/@oJ8hltsIxt0mO1By7081Lx7iuTgdUxJg93cEyoOP4zQTTD2c6exCclxMUx21Q3jCYAVc/5dG9PYJZ2LmFRYtgSMAkCEOMztnEZKiFg0lUANxpAiM5P8tGHwSI8xe0OmOY3XSkoGB3c55FLca9bjILxBgG7szmMVACX3SbFjCheBbu2Yg49XfgNGuexL8PI/29GBwV@OLJ01NHhLF063fpQ/DjzQ4NtSwggF9uHzT8RmizRX3Okoih6k8W3FSVdEsfLEHalxAZH6xSAE@1IBwi1mcZE4BG8UZbAA7nVkGERfOx5q3CBiJ297JiUfNoJeni0WCO8xb04uGFIngNmFCej7/rfuNTWVjhPHJsPigFNIB7NGRw4nJozHb5NwVeBNoQV2S4wFrHF1jRjp2ZJEdBVPYdHmRWp0aOGa60kOXGc6QpDSk/Cjw8zRlz@VMVT3eqPZ5vHYmxSFdn3Vgl2tJOkNP4r3k6xPezAurK7pdjtiiozf6datDyyQyyzhM6NkRlNP26rcRPegQQ3csmcm5nUcaWofXXF6PWSQLEC5jjVNbdEQj5WyfoDlIYl@FyvV4UBv/@jI95ZaWsz7zkq5bBbnABzFYRATfy8kTPKL3sfdrqQXIB7rACNh/zQ8DeE4kWPIQDdN5HXa2BxM3nz5zzpx0YXXDc0hPNnJYshmCZpRsBpwtDa9sFN2TsjKSXftjwCx81Oi2WkFf52KFqtKb@VSXZk/RnP/ZsLuQb7h1iIkHjsXLwwxMIr0QXNPzcOR3rnx6fDM4HvnTGmxC9POgz/N5hO0dwmaEdzLRl0Neo5UWiBrOLerJEU08aojkFeWD5NMck2jAmfgscWEOAoI7COA@zfjD@GAtNNjjZ9uFkZ5p34RJvWAJJWQn6gs@OLlI8IW/V3gjbZ3fAW261o3A8kifZq6pFhkBP2gHYest12BRv4cnPUE/dg6hUwcL4fG10VwrrXpAoHmtcn15KAP2h74w0IcXotiMm5f1q@veuCsjuzMsPS6sNHv3MamT@rrqe@4/JpPhLO6scWC7p11YpZEuQ4wqwoIoYboVS3/U6Kbxk9kxEhpEVeG0H8Vloo/8bekLc8PS/ZZWNTArh3Vgo5VTHGfCUjegdikR7bPKjPppTPlAOAApCMbikC6eJtZ8a88xzjDmDSFmYib3t9DZ/56VXH5Dpw0RlrReKu6ZzMMiXZ@iCtIqL4fYllYLlMI3jw@uAtFsRZ2wlFfr1jhOpvm7K6wPaG4x6c9ClfbatmWXp7GFFhMOtb@mhU4jxNDObM8CjdUWRmxJgljOUBIjMJ6lpVuOSp/LNlgpgZIM86yQrSUmM9I57A2auLN5po0YceeTp6U3IwFRUaCplmaqsrtFG5v4@6JVL9rBNKxxmdIW2VW0gUYy6xwl3JDBg4gK7iKq8PMQxXDNwxN/@dXQFEdAHEu3icQ88jWsQ1yz7LVuIoju8CVC3FMjCM@0MUfQbfQwaWAE2GxzMIFast/QwvCiqnSALcZlYXYM96N3rPWwAhnOhIwbQxyHIVyPMKluEqSrBPyPCY6BS12hQSdmAQGRNZcwhSg@DLFB@DbWCElZoHJJLyE@Q7kkXxNUWCt41MkjesII3F8g3jMbxKOY9p3gN9xQSORYVHUJIHx496O97h6zdGx8c03SwJEjozSz58XhEIMKHrJS55KSysJV0Lzy1M80UJOtpMh7ENp5csnEEwCBJQ3MqQedUe0lMfCGAQzDZORkc27khsX6oTZ0/5Hs3xrH2ldBKMAICHktHaB8RldA8wSLhECBrLRAU8/DFKDaxM7M7SUS1UhcJNTGKFnv4AXZqucahMys0C4dqugG1dHYsirOtZpqC5FKzq2mXEwxitYMOjoKmmgIN1aq0LPswWJ2yEHbciM3gMWBkqbJGLuyh7OwoAQ2MlnPyBhzFf0YohiOGDLO@hJvMUO6wITwJSFethRYJkbqG861P3ABKRGtzoX5ggiy10gOiSw0uQjv132D@fnYoapfwg8FQwxm4o0IJ8RRTe6XCJrET0XoLD4fIFIy6P39UOlPmonHkqrc230fLfJevFbgvdjee6ZhDq0NuPvg326T43wpsDTaf9SiHXz9hPdfMlPAP0ygFK8wNkkEgNuHY0/uGn8S6XXZcFzna9MN@0U9TlzuWi3YjoHZUkBTGvTEMfkgKQvP2sGWEgz8pA1TK@ncvbBCUDERlFnNTGpHepkixcxSf3VWAsJUW8K4n0Bz5F5EkZx4dDVocl4A2KDwe5uyApBeW2C1CBUirniKPyWm8kmb0xS2ZSXzCNRiXbqVMQg8NAiWsbZH/vhRIlZ0JMcO@6qPSaJAypqlwzCbULWfLpI9Ri5bfLRcllwkm/ZiJJ4tJocgW7z4mW38tnJaZKCFdhwDuYMLlQz4pHIAimGCeuhhHBnzhWvZR24/X@z7p/jyR90YFv/w4suiQX8zLsQsRkJMc64QExWQWk00vFE9U57YAyzbPmnIiyL2cH@DeH@wbnR/g7n98U3sKionlQfULb6e0@34ZiA1DKFKh2R/nNsR8lpe0xeOrO0L5d5d0Dzf0Tb84p/b8D/2NpwzuMBsow/sNNbU/3Pu/xHmHvNX9tbz6/n6r3bua945NmE5M@etSjlPVWHrq7WzyW7@bLKxfPCX5Di5Vcy9H8HfcfIvydX1JD/CA/x6oX99TG4lN7HY6m1ymiuXy/AorVT2oJWtb02bWGq6Cf9sreh2V6fJrUyZqv@Y3FqFh0KxCJCcTaobZ5P1PP7vlP5I4od9umKEj/taHVJOG9kQ@CxQXORJLR@EUZM71u5QQxLQ6njcQIo7PzSaIYDReWZSXM@LrAIExMkfPgZy/5ZOmyHyI@WPGVNGE4640GkfxFePK8EKMF148Ie6oN1eRK8o4YTONYFSQgS0unieXcWj6wvJQWEAMPkmSMxkV25QL1zqGNOb4d@t/FeOyUfx0oklwYifbcquuC674v8l1XA6vhz0i3Oy2ifVDkzXOFDfhwxL2O8Oh8GYJf5O0A9GlMoEhoOCDl6z18RLCXvdH9j976VuXDWpofr3YZ1jc7ih7HCqnGdfw8rqXpFW9AlWpX7G87HVZf0LGDde2IZxMjq6ptMdX1436EKC49G0Nj6gTBQ5TGo@5qwUOZDlGrkrHx0HKI1/CCQGJYAdjK77ObrYDQQ2jJXB3PtX/g8AGl4mC0Nr1aEYGvt/cOnm1jAYUojLpN126JqkoNc6Cob@yOeMdeg1f@13ghpm4oHJCC8dVJ6S6g0F14zt1MRGWSKMgxwu92FlOHsY8f4wpcM/CbVKYbgxXdfjYJy6MCHi3U6WoiaglsOhBXRFeHswGEflOWrcVKCf8RqUjw0miUND8HAwGhFwcxz/kgZiSSl5QXBEP6XT6AV1RNCMVBev0cBRBf3rK6Idc63taeHlueSsKxes68XJ43X9pVwp7ziIUJwmMTYX1vHLNfte0rlkQlIHmHGAYM2QQEGekGs6LbwCTSEMB43vKdESciVYkEh/Wf1Nlj250cMjGrv7QccnXnHTwGQ88LbVDakA1sx1PoHszihKx0i1cd0Js7wWKLCiG4bXwcra@jIBRDu@LtoaNGNFizloeeSPpjkC7nJ81TOj2Bhfql7wMeiJ9wqBTel8eVESneGNZv51j9xaVj0iHUBlbKSABXcjze92q3v7lePqbhrElBUsHlJYkinrWsjlz0v0vd3DTA1MRliFl2@2sbrMRO6G6dTXaJFj0L@20b5kA6wbCMMs7gHdoZsqUzXxs@CG1RDV9n4nbY7DKdWQzhqNyw1BuaarJhyNXL3yk0kM6QqxrySSYCyxAdTBgenI7VEPGM@dQvfyCsCAcLf6GCiyh/wTKdfZfJrJmDX1kp4ywFgzmS02sjg7vS4onqnD636M26Zo7fgqBUwOj/@ZtT1NEV/IOiV1WUY9vtQs50smbu@je@19NldStxEKlxF3PNie6vlzryUyzQGEeOTlrEMm//d/Ul7pNkqi03PHHl69oD6VdeboLDP1Kt9V66bCJkzWGKp9yo6DyXiHM32WxyVToTFoTbOUXKu1A1p1y/1k9zF0vc@wVy8tNcvlF95n6HI0xAygQ2CGwTG06JXwXTv2zoSI5c7O@ngB9SKG7n33ev8VTDn6iQXh@PTP54vPculUyvNKOAS/TPF9uwev36KVf@Rlydq/NxpcCV5GvukkC7N9FZ7mzwn6tINDy@EqBM7ZCcYy@nB7eux33oC05KZ8QAG6JVFgHExKd9OX@LIS@iahzIWXs9g4KjvxyXW8z50ylbocBe0S2ypuw/JHt@OVxvDn0u5iBbooF4vU@hgqldGraQbr3T7s1q@OX@@XU5u@wlbLc1ZFaqlhiAMIhQjGxVcVvI4qRjrAVYiqxhytRwQD/y2lnK34WDZz/laqdHt7Lzz7nE8XhJ9URMAt9zotFDcq353S0iiigukwKOML3tq@qR47aaiLKVjwZR@3tykxLQ5iLes@mNyQU9AWOD3CMuXy8sICvcMq12G5XMznPcyIcguthXh/PDTLC2tUuh355ZZrEOkPu3NuSypmizkOZAlzhdVifmXtq8EItogyXki/EAILKaPW8rE7ni6AbBiU9c1LCyAnw25afrq8uH7Q3f7TdxtHq7tus/FtwUk734fktj8a2gCM/Jssi0XAY0eSa5eAwMjFpp8b@j8McsutfBMkz8JaK1hbCdbzL9abK8GLjcbGxkazvbzeaG2s@WsrzUYOk71TlexVtw9SksPkj922H9ftfYLZejG/0W4XCqtrrZWN9kYx/@LFcmN9pZVfXm6vF/wXL1ZbxfXGRuPLUlsETwIYrOa7uHfMcuDn9wt3iTu8XWp7/w8)

`@` on line 1 needs to be skipped in Extended Brainfuck (reminder: `# #` is there to execute `@` in Hexagony, but not in PingPong): `# #@` → `--[# #@]` → (skip brackets in Hexagony and PingPong) `--$[# #@$]`.
Square brackets change IP in Hexagony, call/return from procedure in PingPong.
After `--` current memory edge happens to be `-16` in Hexagony, need 2 to make it dividable by 6 (`-16*10-2=-162`), so that `#` command does not change IP: `--2$[# #@$]`.
`>` acts like a mirror for IP moving right in Hexagony, so `--` is used to get zero cell.

`_~~^xy` or `~~_^xy` on line 1 break Seriously for some reason (it enters infinite loop), so I use `~_~^xy`.

`r` on line 2 makes `Register3` nonzero to fix [`R` instruction](https://github.com/TryItOnline/alphabeta/blob/master/AB.cpp#L126) in AlphaBeta.

Agony/Brainlove `]@@(~~[` on line 2 was changed to `]++(--[` to get rid of `@`. When `(` is executed current cell is nonzero, so Agony enters the loop, but Brainlove
skips it. So Brainlove jumps directly to the main code as before, with current cell being 2. Placement of `]++(--[` is chosen to satisfy Delimit.

Extended Brainfuck code is on line 10:

```
~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]
```

`~*` opens loop only for Extended Brainfuck, `*` fixes Agony, second `~` sets current cell back to `0`, second `*` is for Paintfuck.

After `/` on line 1 moved I added 4 newlines to be able to catch Klein 010 after it falls off Reng/Haystack line, Klein 010 code is on line 580 now. Before adding
4 newlines it fell off to the last line plus one, and after adding 2 newlines it fell off to the same line.

I inadvertently relied on tape being circular in Brainlove answer, it is fixed now by adding `+` after `>[};]` on the last line. Current cell should be nonzero for Brainlove
to exit `()` loop at `\)`.

Answer (score 4):

## 280. [Befunge-96 (MTFI)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/befunge-97-mtfi), <s>13237</s> 13164 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退    @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo     anet/112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBq
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
 xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa


















































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu?1&&1Prers 6 4>8370::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>Exps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody/'='d  Float#  +- $int 2;#8
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print(#~$+/ .---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce`  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @,,:1'<
#  |!o51@!00:8:8; ; ~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~-<~ -<<<~-! `=> #
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  >[};]+ pppppee^ee*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsNls8jbv7W5ymuzbdwZEowuFAlBNoApdVSCBZrNjZrwxq7EUXnk8qxiN1rojeeWV1o6w1mFbclgKR0ivDoWf9ANaftlQbGj@wew5J7MKBRAg2TNSxD5skajKz5OZJ0@ePPl1smn43V/8IoEPO3J7407PDVhg@QFrefa55Wns4Zg9MGy/kF@VJAy143WGfcsJ/JKUYDpjjnXBDhzTboEbC9wzy7HfWR745RkbeG7HM/os6BoBWGyIxR5Zvff99wEz3X7fcFo@hFxl7MgAz/bQPGNG0w88wwxs1wGvNcZeOD2j32wZDEJY3sCzAgJfYADCPKM40z7rjD11Pd/C5E3L91103GBsy@oPgnEVLEUIYXi2@2Tn2eczkTcZ@9yAnA161mgmL3qOvbQtrzUTQ9fZVyf7@7Ouefal6jps/3r@9FX2wvONnjELf43tDAP3IJh1L7CdjuUYLK9tavlZz3X20DOuRdlgnmW02nbP0mzHZCrrWr2B5TF0YW3XgyoLrF4xV8w1diYxNRPjFieeM2Ar4cMMr@ODp3tugdGCmhjYVou1PbfPDMe/gJT0zdwkPILdnCYHEzIIhMbe@BC7ZTHfsQcDK@CeUFzLI29ImfVs50zi1Hfkua2haTsdCGcBXgfDgMrkSyZEq7KBoGENDSxBWODBIAvHbt@K14UPxAu59geWabdtkyPHGgWW40N5fY3ZUHcXdq/HWlYPIkygmxnmu2zox5yaPaOrmZqEyMVUWP@sx2xmDgaMe0ExIEv7uSKz@u4bm70D/17XZ6NBn/l2H7wD0223LYu9swZdiM76LWaOTanlSgweczBTusi2bEEYx4IS7h59G3AXIEqdNmSvxZqxcJAXyjeV2nBcQKHHHKPPKcIcjAkDACaK0XZdDd1bruU7yYBduN4Za1qmgUXHxHyr0zaGPUjRbmOVAC3YPuu78IWKdBhkCyIHiA@EjYlJcwuCyYRVbA2gcWIVu0gyUN9hTV94BtCI54u6DOw@UIgdJH1mGb6NXAui@JbTIuoYRPzMhdLGK56d29D4ABVDj2D7lkfkT3AZlgJAGhG9KheeHQBVYCl22JFleOzEs6wUp1XLN40BUmo8SUjMxRQCLIhGxLm1ldw73E8CkfIYmjEAovRWT771hWQwrcKWG2X4VWS5LO09e8Qul0/RzPkmEPLAU4wUq3xgfvb01ILfSG9mO96VBFAlwEqPZd1BkDXUAWRQDSCDWQONaFLP89qgF0uYbc3UQazp8FAtqA1gBOyrDJXMHHoecvgJUo0zKHTPdTqATyisN3R4la/noAqA/lp@hlnnFtIAryP3gjB80gUKgX8IGuMuvNMhhEK3A81RYDRM13d7QwoHMf0A2yRgBaIixIM2@4q1DbuHUcAfQfFce5YPxIlxhk4La75vO1ZLY2E2iPN40B7PITkDgJIDtIZ@jL9QpiAwVIRLRUWvj7/5O61OB@DsmKbrtQS5fgXEblL3aFBmoYNjSLCuY/QoWxAug6nz6JDAudGzW8TpDGcskqBMUKoX7rDXYtRQL2xocl0DGK4FTMIMLE7k7jCAPGZY3zjjXNHmlAsF7xtNqFhKgNKmYqvswS7UkgnNnGhG7Q@DdpGpgz2W9LOvlO2Ssr10akHmUlpqZTmb7ZSB4LQVcgJb8ibK@Wpnqrv4inWAUIYDLF8rA0TAHPdCEI6uriKZEOcBdNnedHu1RpY5DCysXWD5TSpJ3xhT5Bh7KRAMYD0nB4dYRVCPXs81WqKOXyKd@BfAWLusaQAzD5BpI57iOcX4kLcu8hbHh07MejuELAFPAhyNg67r5JlqMtmsuBBASU4VP5lJes1kSsOORkmV7YqptW2npSS3oBlVAWfJVNmsmDW7VC/PRI/nAcBcIBjkNJZipmRsfSe2i3yoN@iiEAFBHX8ATNTDkpoGkIOPPVUAclqGNYlQqXsDVkFM7sJKAp6ahh8RBrUx3oYwvoqcT0CYtInppmm1Yi0TWjUgOPCvsdeei10@5QkrFHiBg4kaHRDrIDIvyA4vCE@JXKaLdAbU4SC0psWKatMGqsb2A0xaEHGsbBB8Nc/DADRO9bEaRVKBbor395MWgDVtsD60d2/MTAuZCHATi/cQmMiQGpQPwixz2yyn5guF6UZzrc0EXnZH/Q5w3XfZG5sGFj7eOpBzsDbIzj3D6QyNDjQJ14Eohmlag0BwHiiJHwBvme1AyFEVvaHmd6XlB7NpU68QyjyTNKj9UO2Jvs1AdiFkcRUELZTnuIDPWtAoTWoG06lDgPOZxOXXGGQqA6/lBVkIu3QgMt7KoXEDAV90bWilF5Q7hzM63qvMJg9O8dSBVavtKGnMjF69n5e0bOSE2VgIQsUavQ4HeksEVZ1yoMqPO9wM2fD7cwC7URaBs8dctayhAe3dArPvOu4coIDICCwGmfbh9QCi1TFKutAThXIUNdZI/I2qCOoMuAa0fKC/bhAM/BIwfjvoDpsaUEr2xBsfBIcOEks28MZ24HJzs@c2s33Dh/aZDVPImsOmPZopELlFdfjGl85Bomr7rMKQ9QLVKcm2D3yT3HcxcMxLJimHQPC3DAEpkAaIUto@seJ9YCrHY8dU5CmilDNMxrYrp8CAESPUfIHS2HQ234DTbC4xWDwzWhZDZX3PJIMaEzIRPAanbEn3pop2xzxK92QZXm2j51vwdYa9HlqHDudyCu/8U@xSuncPWJtCydn9Qc827aDBfdn9@0JIYEswcEM5qI1CUAri3BMjZA0YCoQRvQ8PrQXuMUmvSgoKcu9qKmHL81yPpxt0PejUyQGDSXGkPrPPhq0ZrDrohuiUcQyBArIZgMQL4ysu98wQwTSmZvtelkRMIalgfM40K0wW8Cipa6RDrlhjsogmhMSKyFqsChXMUYbDhcBzscVjC7d44XfdPnZt7CWJjzgegIG67eCEhcTFCpIqjLlSRSRQkPSfTGpvXNtRLpNLS0vJUrIK4sLS0jaYttC0jaY0mLbJpJIJw2loohgZMqFvjWKgWz15VQshj1J15AUjHOK8sweKUSuVVusZo6aLbx6/KSAy6C4htIofgJNMVSpoTKXk6gUUVGu2p0u/i13@senZA4GEL4xzg9sFFlYJDUC1rod1UUac34yTfsWzNB@GNmZX8ZKntdxp/fTytJU@vUpmMHaqbFSaUChIT@lrHc8dDpRcqrZWUvV6KlVbBVGsWUnmkiuKUlRhUArjqtRnxVTa4NhWkhaIAsrpaRKQKvBTM7sewRtl8qlUhCrIB0p7MHJQktplEdJvpuqpdBLippIZGIhWkknAjIlI8KnQSPlTCDp8/iVHzG46LRGBwhgbf9dkCXDDIfx09KPhu3fIuDmMZkRhvaHBx4MDESB74IRhNfScGYKHXs02w05kKo3P3TYf4@3ia@/JvmSNqLY@P9zfe16hZLqGfwYCldrBsFk/AHHC8FoatKPesGVJ88IAzwSTOckJzoZg4h3TZKrLKJhq8kzE@kqTLYAGjBanBDSXqb3@dBH8LuR3d6oMBITcKeZNwpsZZokHn5unKMl96K52j59MTfr1z0CYYqbfw8kP1eMFAGt2hTu26JMAdmj4rt0qsQMacTogXQNtgXDdimY2HNdRsSMIB6duPCE@vQMhyA1FTRSj7KkwCLhtj2CAn8DZIZT9cAAGJAQMDBDmwFDb0l4Sc5MZMEmcf4OR2Lyh0BGXIjXTn7ROGO2AcdAzTGDh0@BOZXYKAIEDZbPzfVLla4BhZDQ1MKJZidvKCHKkaTiIv5ZNo@6h7XcRvTCQwi7QawNWcciNY0nC2gEzQcTvAKatkS36ImjhxxjlseErKRyL7vBBFlIZDhAwU@FcJEnvrmkOPQsGCujLJ3/YnnNue66DSNb2ADSwojLWwQzweegFMtrZOcg/WozfecABY9ec9Rhu41BnkWv60Loct@d2XLYCAZA0NY0T9oGDc7bQaQfGAFqU/Y4QtNNxnfEMDVpWNAu8vookz2emMGSWwmtvoBdg8ws9CbCgzMcH39mD3lov5HKQ/9CWoycqZAzKbBnR0WSTAGJdo4d0gzX5HWvQHXtT5OS7YhYooKlQaph8Xs4A@RlyJVr4O4oab@TcBdp56NUKTfPKvkcDIpyKHIwXlH5K@ODNBkqYmHFG1xAVU0CvVfikfpFxnWan@FZYdedqu@8GRvYrDVg0viQcHqg2k/1scimZVVV8y@TF8lWWbVnnWeRSE8ijPZypmQN7ZFlmFn2xc2OhYS56Qs8FqDmFx6EXFJN/QxxEMWfL30mnkbFT7qK0eaahkz/pDi3JMrsuk09hfBUvmQwdRNduWSpgHqRfHJRF0cQalxS4QxjTtqye3beDA1qF6Dk4cNOIeWvItYTvLvCbCYAj24LRCJ9tmXQyuFIw6aOcDg//HDg5QfUDpnGUelYruzKB9tR1vS5Obek0oZKPUN8XHlnXH7S0YAQAeKw96t/9sJ9/dvhor3G0c/K4kh36XrZnN4FHtKxGH0byPWgOCx7MG8537gHt2I7bt6FEIch3Z73nrhtw4QGXQu72JDBiCOPJo8aTg4fPd55/W2SOenS7P@wZmMfS8kyACMYxhbkRjOk2XZAtnOFCSCBcHD48fBJC@eLFk4OdxqO9o8OTGJg3w55t6KPs4KyzqEBfYBCmazmO@sNea3qNisboU1MogtnggLPMYGDOVBXeKrrxRHFIqqEHisjYPaoqzmkbOGvvsbye29xsNY1i0VpvmWtrG22j3Wqt5fVioV0s5As5eG2sb1rsPQVXVWtE01Zg4lNCOHuGaUDm6aNra6GEA@NwEySW8dx8Rb43ZM4sFKyNtU1j09zc3DTyG61VI1/csKz1jfZaLmet67l2s6gXV2/MXCwbKFpNbH2a/oJWhzMl5AnMT4HPVHPgmQdZ74K18vn8ullob67mW4XcWqu5mSsUW019w2huWrn22qqe11tmXi@FcYHHAmPIdqHCUKp0QDQNvVQdPFNS2JnGq5jWTcOFdcFwlleRxQzChXEcOAiPNfQYimVxgBm6F9A9XBTH@Snhvo7ufVwSn0iyZI0cRcAiBcSVcc1rho6b6BitiU@tFgOrFPxznv/iSALypZ67QuAXuKoeK9@lrpP7edBuTznnyflMxa6sN3FeJWe@pj69mi0Ke81rbuAI3hrB42vxc@Fd85obOIJX4PBwDX8@uBmfeUEjYOsEDNf858Ka8ZgTMIK0QZDi@wQmfkXyW7RJQKQ113thpAj2JsHm6/@NN34DRe2GWP5HauYN5AQksScuyM9PbFy0aE@1GCkagZ9KcjiNMD2Lhj5cdsmez4zs1HM5Ho@3fds5c2mcHJkaOU0vYHuOYvfPetdjtmFkQa@poFEeQjlmQe78frNNrzkBsI@dnYUkD5riFT099KxG9jl9cLJ3Xg6mp62nkm9a7SEMerJN20HzLcHUzSKFbDeb9qKggAncPRF@5wQrsedDGHjmtTVND0e5uEwELJrPOZ8cHFLApkFjtum1DjaF/GDoBRBLfP/rd1tQCderqGuMaegXGRqOdYHVpbYX1piIihZ6za/dSSdPiCHTbSBNA9eLjV5kmA@aal9Vu4bXxxGWqG4gUHwBJdxAazznfOol/M5PpMQIydNrKsyx@8y8tpcmcF3mw7B5UjczK0E8XRpe4yIsYYQPgm2LInlY77xGrBEfDsZEHehz5uRwNn/hgg2bbHkIusNgyN@4y@G2GrUH@LuptYqQuYLR1C0Qjo2mbd1Q/55xNmy5Ksh4VGTM2PqcsJPS0zSd2u4ZZ9zYQOP84vMCenanA5KE@C4KdtGFUQ0NR7MX9LmNRHxn6A/UJlRWAG2IbNQq@jek4PX4e1EQW@wFjAyLsWb36HWHSo@Ii8gFhDlCNG7PUmNIs2fQ3DOaYxykdz@dyjBBEm2A/VTMdDq3ih1etOQd31K1OD72khR/c3N@bL4xjKNk3sAqyzeEqXzqmMostojdUrHQh9l9o6fmWzHjQuYeThpPTHOC0oyNavYMH0grENVhnUP10esmcsdOyoQBlzcx3UDsk@yEOx8WLaILDiZaten2bB@bdm8RM51dd5ykiVvz6BWbjLbnIbZF0pLfVSPTfL7gmgGuYC8gtDtwOb54jMvzMcrR3EVIM90L/C2UMrruucXf8/u8d3NzdQeOpfaIJGxzbufSut6LgBPv4mme1QfhH4iJZlt1Gury3Rrh9oTC@uDt9VrAvVD0mo/8s7mFCczeXPfphhPOiMTHc3dsDL7dc312TO@bcAkF833@nt8M4mi3DUel5aO4eX40kakB08Sk7AJiMHodt7de7GQNeC2kmKHXxo5EfO/KMiOWp@u3s7xQvnIdXXwX9hVnWe/strqjlQwPNzjEjDd02/P4nljDXFxAIFHctTS/cPu5IsXUsnx4vagCPLN7YYzD7y/RHS3CbtgdDcYkr4P4iBE2i2AIPC7D/zKprd2cWutuPO0a2I3bChGr3LOeBb0fva9VKcvn9E@Moedyd@dw7d7QGlpzGdxh842FG/xvGMXcPVM5UYxlMTmKE0g4NRqFeifGn3fKNXb8aLuRwQCzhUZ@q3g0l98NQLAf4Aj9CAxHaLgeseMMB1OVOzUKdJ7fjLnuIGzZbmsqk@jzqRypeLsQNiX9@xb9bhyc8cEkLoVV1nK5nBCKYtPdU5abBm2rUdw3Nn9PJUwuk5QnYbHn9GLG@WlMZl6h6u0zX8U50Ltxp/yiGQUKvLmZdWzHCsb4viOjbbpu71NqD/hty0Z5D6RYXCK6rRavyVJi0xybTJv4OOnSbC@aMOF9kRjNAuJwzH4TIcQnae9UwyoKN9BAOzPWm6eQYlO@t6UCPTzNS/FNFr3FgqqYjNG1orZxY2Pk4q/btHoG/4zW126Ct6mt3ggvklaEXE2rYLhyxtfKJmuviRmWNRgDsuwWDIq6Vt8i6w2jCaP1ZuiHn4WBRi7@5nhrtDK5KN7ABh7h4HtqXS4mRQWuA8O4wPA6Fo6Derh@LlwX8eVw/n0ucg/6RsfiZ8puYpyTqRHcYc1HjxPj/EmSEt@fZkI0vknkZlKAxnRmjf3wOxfg07EJ9Tns3z7LN9PuTdrSdFtD17Jzlx1uEROdrtt1ulaX7xmKbIuaB1BkwE8D3lQIyH@nazLiT/H9THHM9txe7y6YRf7IuaXrtufmaQ/PqLUg6ifBHRtN8BCfW2cPoZsnBFF/v6jddK0h9Fa@G7gDSyXboqA9nFzi70VcNFwG@mVnrW6cUQCMhN9fFr55W8SO4QaDAX0ag97QpxdFVelo4Q1DNj51TkkSXTLX62jv3H5TE47aPv8@hQpfwGyaeM4FtzBxyrY6btPs2rdlumkZgWOfZcM5Jm69cdg7iOHJZuojdNZ6NqDXG2tIL5W4/zF@DhZVupiu4h1bZJhPBSW2O/S8MVJ6OBdNUwa0JWtyZnnCVab3Z0STxXy5Aw2LciVWHud4kwyBO/fCHWo3rLmIhcqFZElSO0roqpUDMUdfOG81tX001qZWV/lrkTQ1U37KVGx9@FMmXsW2CpqCtGPzw@A@RVNTi91zuzinO@z415kkXxZogWCGr7m1v9PBU@B3qHxe0dCXGY74LKqDfC@L@@Xh24DaHFo3LvEUblzjoXB6TzVcGz4N@EC9DhdO2PXsgc/fTG3n54oe15etr4cazx97izprWW2@CoOm22TGvuvhqS0QTlTTs3wTJ/GRt3NJjPMxx@0Aj1d7bBI4DDu3CNdXyueSRNR3ql8/szoGbul8YuPuzt4cSgGoswvmtwH91tDw7W8N3cCaC2920fw2cE@Njm0@nsJ8CCzEqNj3xz9TTQGdriP/omv7dGAmNNwwcYVExskW6awBI4d5Q76ZhYLoePnNczMxkUvsN2fqAQv3pUcGXKpAf2NuWvPWANwBDT7HZLpp@t8OaHpXfOdS1fyNBzclfzHsD4a@@MxPnfYGxSfH@2fk7l/YwCrVt8ChWdfoBfMn0GPTuyC9ic50Ylwkz3/H7rkd9p1ijoGwB8IbivdzCO4hdOtHRgAtwplDwJT2Al4@u0SLMycq55L@W6AJa5WptmMHN88SBYEBo63wi4XhHRAe@8w@wbf24FMhqCfzMfLkRkkWZICx2UO1Anzfnc@angVdKFdmEG2Ru7kzM4EWj@nwPxoj/QNx6heJWbvhaoXodxzrIj7@u3HRqYSdresMAxXPF9y4nD7pZNZv7GRKbFRcj9EKU7619/RFKk4ytAf3NhHXgjHm0O@NJ6aF2yFmKNF2QMpbzJynQ4cDlUcWaYl4TrtFb4mzM8Dza9QHPHLnDaaOxp4V3Hk0Bj3KsP/IMnER9Na0n7lPQb6Dvm0AXLj/3OLH06aYy/yIGO2Jaxo9wE/r1mSOCeyczmMybjcGVhPqtzcxzRfY5gF@ZATGAgGLpiNpcBmZbqUVu9e0vDc0zxgzLxovT2fosTWigctiguENUg1Mk0vlOOM31VxmV4z8ges6/E1cOQcf/enN3Af6C3rdffFfw03UU93h3PHfdGkPI/UD/OjkouJ6VtPt8TcWYUFP6Nh8n4Ph2ZaffWI7wxG5ra8xFcS5@SMkvps4p22QChhoSOESa7TNGHfNCd45MwwDOfnc8GkHwvzBz9SW5rvvd@oanuniqpwwfOKaXOxs2i1sPdqzzXdKNKFiRsDUDHMoTjndltVev9mn18LBS6y2n1tNPPvXpLOpgTGaJ1lOn2ETjjOnyEK2ho1/nSlHMDxK3T5jNju2m8a4PaAXMfWLuYQSJvfMtsx3RupO46pYi6Ip66xBQ@C5jWp6mx7IQD1LDbq46TMb3DSXHp4PnrMgM@xbuAY@vRK0kJRcv0t04M5f9Y9YrWeJneO4axEafWhGfqvuLCRUBA//hw@/yEKX3FhfQ@0Jw5HaAUZ2@z4DyPzQc8TnLsR25PpB2x4dDlAvlust4ixYrAJEgQ9vBGhaWVQIqD1n2OPTIZ3YtrJ@i4Z6IBi2XTD1iHkHlmo55yrpixpdL5Hrkcqb7A4qXAusliomSHBZQ30SymVRMPGds5YbZ5O4q1XPcsSO1tfEPtd5yL3wo1VJ8FAHPn2zA//o4MnhiTbw9bmtIJzGxN2KQ7uHq4zU4EI3QAyZrklvPYMaxw55ku6hqXNv@WIuNmP2xvBiy7V8hx6eS8w@PNbV3ScHGgZYUEd8yUWFDy4nTn0Wb/AYdI2mFRhZY@EwC32tYL6I@fjk6ZP05Jw2U3a7ntu3UnHv3ePjDHAo9sXxXO947H1oUW13tDD6wZ6up@aQ/AuHljQXMdc5KS2CdGLBYBkq7DE/MnyreGa6A6t1Mh5YX0Hfiwzev2Py6wsL@cw4tzvYctnmQkRR42ab2vpaKrZ93fJQPVn4XVSfZ/YAOaxJnyz/LNxNg4LHatZbnS983LRhYVYIYjmxkeLTIum569Qa2Cq0jE4XTVnD/1Uzpuv6IjwfG22oV1ZYWFnTAeYJJj33/A7L3ZYY/qiRkxoAVan2rfvsN9Q@sPssvnD1QDiCsblwF89NACLnOfuSxSlCUt8W6QUCbsbPt4Kb7QkFIr4W6iIUh4FJpArH3OBomOYQp4mBzDVGARXFSKdTKUnEegzCRR8VnWEkn860A@GWWS40otDThR6DwqNKE4UtG2yrAiFSqTLXDQScD3qBoVVmbTsEDL2O3XEgA2H6pKcNOTTXz@EzGKcHIdRajS1fjkq5kn6F6kJKMqvXeX7xoUT2RgNSsvacR68tG/XKclJVk8vJU6fEcskouNXzrfnBjamwkFn8iAxH2OUKGF3SnhjhssxVWoGgiPrfuobTgtYs@CGU3@OKmbjWrxM8@vCXf9gSavFI/WPf9o0eIAS1WwJr7roX2zzdEF2DgeGRjjNSvNTjOqHU3R2hLY1rw4PKerF/UhQquYQqTbAc8XWEKBecbnALBJ6wDzhZ8NxEp6VFwlGssFCm2xv2HRiitIKur7Fjmw7PD73JcTihYNQJPFznbGXYAWtZuLWcdCLQsn7Pdc8iofUv/5ArIiPNCOLEepg8aRSMpYgKEHTS/mWa7hByHQJ5Z3muCKIgkg0zGOL@GVJoSe4p1BdAGtKA1tVQPxglw5WE7e4cM3WPJVHNDWqpKdttZXnn@edf1XL1ygfWz1r/9bvZ1KVAnPwZNE5fzrAwSPkKCSvuXQDviW@SycsjmScYqY2wxbzIBa8PVPPJiQw1R4Q05rqDsNngQJt0FEbUKFQFKWimeg534vZJbR8RrHVBisLofLKDUhzpG/WhgYE1RaB5q6ssK0O@r0M9DlgBEkRlawZX2@eimk67b6HSK4yyPGLvGYlTwMv1Qg5sHJE91LPWrzwMedhq/ChY9pHVHNKhiPO8li9UqDjLjcpWlUwgz7uowLD26nSUz6mno429etYPkXp6Ovosl/8asO56EOt@Flve3rNHl8taNff@vW@MmSxfJcv86BqwieXLo4OjveOTnZMXx1ALVyFj2@cHWENeg1REZ9K7bo9UQwJecBD/Cfwnsk2YICogTqWk@OlhCipwLavyMjfGWNNU7Fuiz4vvWzH/6wEET4M@Ror6BaACg4gNsYaF5wogmYgrdPoRldkBydGeFiEGDwjO4aWEKplVAFkqIOuOqGKLC7vN3e6CsVuh3Iy27blBEGNRerXInxdxLgqu/l7KPTB8/1cvN4dyc7kpzA3lhqCRaxhnf@fgyYvne9PRwk6euG5lsyCOzXPmjC2NTweESgxJW42IiPtiKjKTKQK3is6M60a2ggsLiiWYo9nnkYlCKf@yNCFMwEwFVXTXhRSiKJQDlG5QEJk91Q9j9VgWwz46Bu6SFzFiAvtyBDrMuCYLyAlSNa3hExYDoQp0hU3viJi44NdJPy7@ZMIWh0XDPnro8za3oKuKeh2fwX@sVwpN@TobMdGd6XWmsjz8epbTgQKHYVNl3kexZY4IeZnnXY7yi@qBIU@tNwYtINPAWJyGh166Zwz8UBRMsGduYJXY26FLGndCZhLJF6SZ2uAavalquY5q0uQD40cYdYf9FsE72D@uoHTGRTPi73GaGzrYUUEgrlhb6MQIPFRCz5UVcA23HOWu0L0adpU03@oLXYuRlOCzc9u3YTBJldBGGacHnBJLIwqOCtpJ1xLb6fkgk7Sg@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@3sACS0cOIZp2W/cgb@zu3fwxeHR8TW9dhQyORssyZLVrfSpqmVq9ciQjPI9jdSH@9njpw/3Q1TGczWZ/MAQkw3/s9mcl9psThek/pIfP76eNnlcS0jP3RUw7aZV9@nMzHXoE99sLOAuP/14LVUldXlVq29VT53EteTfz9O8ntBWkLjAdOqT3vXkbDYxi9FNKyd404qvhVo1dFSpgSeuA/dsoqBDOMQ8ePAQCnAAScuGoRYxT8jAIZ//mWiSyvOrXnxifXyOiNRnRzmKhTwJL4XBpjVRfCo0fnYNv9uzmxJ04C1UAcz1dYUKqSJNX5o/6NmBkpKEklgQJVBBq7gaZlQaabQZRUlhMydYGXaTEtEQXkqCRgDwkkdDv8uO3EFsZuuRFZqegzTCHg35xgSLfTHsQ7g2fZ5bNDML8okKkQFRySirfFQNLUvoEB2lUU8rpFdDTaKi4Fq/VVBGKa1rjVp2Bxi4kspAS/9MB7Eq0nKChSa9ok4SeBzH8Od4gDSO0k9SJTuaADdqhmY7LWukoG60Uh3kU3RPXrw8T6bkazRA@mx3Qw2YM4ptw4ZoBKJFTJTCzjS2zeg@mBkFwZubqF@uj/ucKwxSPA68J2CE/klp940BU4akbtpnGiOrcqo4GT/wUkytcqVNDkunaVQNH/IAqRmDtslEhMMUnIVUshWoHXT1nRZ@3tkDVtM1rQ5mSiTFlnFGbRe6cpyLSkkwSoIoJQJbwbplJcwRp16NUx7EQX@JVEAy1Lk8x5sUBdOig4u4oFKz6v2Y6rxJC@RY3dwsidqYZjWbDMjiOpfXsgB2DgsJpVTAr9DCAVjDa0Hw/hhc/wS28OBLy3EsQBDQTN@APtgYApF5qUx4F1Rmco0EpZDgWXws1HpARqevl9hLXvZwe8xytkyTM@Ur6FNfn2Kn2hbd6jj7P2a1bPlSWe5VxlkQdFJVZblb0dOrK@n0srOiLDvY1d@/j3M6V8sgSTQ0GCKNIJC63EuVgZ5B8qgsO@VlY0tZblXyKxQDrDBIu4QIH/ysdrlsXGWX70NPnQEXjzdeZdknnb45TdOvIH/YQpazGaCZS1SBShdBYfLLdjqNedCWG5iBD9nT4zTx7NPjLE0flYU0mu30RXOb4apRTVy7BosjUDiLigbGnkfGLk5HNcLAqCUpXBqf47dA9uAJf4krJowWZy0/Lv7L0z53ZyyC3yVJ3SLXoMyVKgMCRwogEa0ZI5UCZvKLXyT0dSYry9vrq73zdLKQK8NLLxdYgX22fKqq@eVagiUeLNcNI2jAwD27cnn6qNg5Z1Y7v/62Zre1t8XKUeasfnT09YfGh1ejcepUSSZ2D9/L@hqE32Cb9Lvrs8HyC547KiRMrGSlRHZFv7@Rzb5@/RqEXnxqVa0aBtHqHz6kasl6bQPLtAhQUsnnU8e2bWfZ6cBvteBXdruMrmarJ/iTTisqucBLrXG37e3@qI2G0Y7V6Qz3jDF3txND/OwHIu7T77x8@RINL@lh755zd5bgEJkIV2oYhQTL5/J/@adLV5nLo8bWX36vn7WW8HOInx9ePUXzsV74bGnps4cP19YygC1uPvrO0bd3dnbWHmUKR7XC9pqaW9r6iz9fWsrnt/LZpbrv6/Vk7exrOZ9bk7W//P1k4@joW76PFYbPKtPBiO8i/HRWKLAz9g6eszbDfzK/a8XMBpqb7Xcs8S6h63piTH8NXGfAgXWFmM/0s8T06vbGf/vx4dtEkKjmsy89@AaJt4n1YoIbwQC21dB2nqgmtjDY@lVinK1UKmDc@G//FuJXvwA46DPegle1EMJaHyeqaoWivE9U18Gg5/OQ7v/93e9iDh7U4JHXNvLydh2eFXq2pER1BJ7V6sE@y1fzK4J89OJ9/X4s@07QBQHkNKEX1w4fkNW2XPo6@IXHcKwgq@v5U06enFr4F@dREhPnLuAM6pq5iemgZBYuEP5lgugGCIdoh5uFA5ETd3g5G@7lqWGsbKTX8g@c8kvxRIZ/uOc53ii4vvTg9aNsdqsKMgA@pdKD07DpZdlGUXbdBzgtyEaI9DJ7EiG4KueKeTmTyTzA8CMVn1FigkHGkcQSU6hNsImNxZ0SLIzGJmE@NdwePn/17//qJ3/1Y/r7Cf3@s5QIt7WptfN6NXyAhuSqJ1@eCuto6gHWVH/O9Nzn75OF1eQxmKDh6JHvpESJRLWKL/oXNjLRd8ZN@FQjC4WYRJkfjgn2EyI1ISU@ZLMMq4Sdh8V5sFRaKpbWS/lsg82U5AFUk5zf2JTr1XwhfwhVp8tUcZuxUMAht7eX4I/@4Yms@F4iF@FMQa4/S6x652eWrUuJWqJWr/OmXY3X0W3Pc00tA@1pZGnEy504lxIqMLJ0@jmQNhMkDs9p@tbnRVrTGsKMBhe@rqq6AFVK/AM8VYklLuGpf1ipfVgJU65VhWFLrVfTIkPw0RoP6mn16qqmvUqXy@IfpMVyZMMHPgx@UJD6lapuvQJgtWmwyTU3ue4@QOgcOL21xqstAJ/eqm1V3F36aQ3Erlp/Va1tTYMQmXvwIK1BLTwAANXlOkuBKKqqS7WFZQCAdYXBcAbq@GrrqnpV27q62tqC/y16X4kvuF5tXfunz@RZEGbiX0eqOq1lq6dZ0dqrdbBr2Sq6aNlTMFThC@Ggz5ESl0iQrFZXcXhVUWv6eqFOEgV7yp7yx3HgH36hFV3Q4Sm6Ofzl8BBhmMiZu0iJFWCy2ZK@kl/NFkafre/lgVP5mHRelrMraHiP/T2IaZtSAsc@m3wItEkOrz9@83/i7/TjN/8arFBOvJaVfJtv8e/JO/x7G@DfiYl/z9/iHzt5h3/PA/x72sS/Ix//Tt7i304T/076@PfwLf5JiQpjIIsub@d6ufOcfqafgcFmORgKdHNdvQWckeUslhvnxizXd/UWmCz4y4HJzrVZrsNyTs7RdfAEQ8ByAZra8OnAXxugePBn53IIPHfOIJUe8ltSVk/f9w2WOpVqLPnaAvFR07Wctm436qj4CmTGciJ7eprlUjXLr5VJadbVFWs09p49ajSy2GZPn7qHk//Dw37ceuN//9B9euj2Xfg/PDx8egq8t5p@kFYfwFOpprfEZztRLW@fllSk8bA5JbJb26fVVRXN62loIXl0S3/iM4EI3@rSqZS8gB78okyCQvnivHxRJkNk5YaGCCCCcQPEKgsBA1wg3unLLAkEF/CcE1yyofECPEMTN2RfXpyiWAwDoegf0BG3/j382//f@n/6gim1egrawOXVlkJPCv9SqcuryyvxrqYURViULfhDB7BjlMurKhop0CWYakqqnrq64m7wVlJbHGAV09iqUuRJQOBGiShNSpe/lL/fL6bNn9NkGeTjyrIi1jdPT0e5XKrcBJdokcN4T0tlqTJtIlpu4vImDIv1FIUorJXL@go359fy5fKasGwUy@WiMC8ryub1p5rb1tdBjFlbS6XK5ZwICwPgcmgEEJZvmGVs4@VECjPLG76Sw2lWupUoKZfk@/cVcYnX9mCQun9f38y9fx85NRot22s00H31/Xu5IeN@o8pmAey54vv3wHOSKddTnrl8pVtRdfZZvkopbLoelGoDvJmezU/S7Bq@EQSe8s4eZGTcDO7LKbpJIJdzvdPkz3/0ve@dJiu4A4Vc13QEgKmwwtbW@lq1ur4G5vUiFFxe5lualE56U09dLWdlXlwmLycTwksvbqTI9SqJ/iyxxbar0FB9fNjlVYLqj60VUkpzbKUuwSV00zc3uSNbW1eK6U3xV1lKseoKE384/lpNr61srDzAAdho/oOstXxpVJLZbPKqcmmUcFLuqmyKe2vw3KZx//7qJqC0mCufSo3Go52TnQZe4ItbDqCfZehIfFrC5eSBl6zRDGphs17D4tVPk8lS@QFVvl4ssESyLMKpSWD5rLjJ@X3C9yW7jSe4RwR25reSGDB9YxV6Xeh0pQFt/9rIsRauoHvMbbeXwBGqkDVxs4Nv9XrhZT8XrtdrXdgta0lKHD3Z2d07yeS3QB7I7@/sZvLHLx4mdLQWJnbyXkX7872dR4cvIMLRk72d473PD77ae3EE7r70xntnWJZhDS2rcTEcXrxlb2y7YQP2ekPbtl3Tg0w0LMsaQLDwKVsWs0zbN968MbwBPYwz7Y8/@8HHn/1PH3/vRx9/7wcff@8nP//mJz@A3x/C70f8@6N/s1nA98@/@Wd/8PF3fw8c/zP8/hP8/vTn3/z2d/mP7H8Gv/8Sc/sz8YuF4z8JYP36z7/58e///Jvf@Cn8/oX4/fT67zf/dP7vJ99f/MN4P/6Dm8P86N/C7484rDDsj36Xu@H3Wvjf5eF@46cff@vf8f@/EH9o/L2Pv/Vn@BKWf/rTv/gvH7/3H/L54l/8q48/@NHH7//44/e/9/H7P/z4/X@c//jb/0rPxV9/8PEnf/zf/@SP/vuf/C/0/4f0/qO7/H/86T/96//rr//jX/@J@P0p/P4dmP70r/8DkO7f/vHP8P/Hf/y3/@ln@P9//Mu//eP/9W9//X8nw@9ww//zL/4Nf//N937wN9//53/zvW8WvH9w4/ubO7h/8w/gcvd83gXOXcr1qS7f/FL5@VWwMUkFaIBu4mF5EG0fji1WlnIsx/gL2uBP/snH3/41IO3fgoBg@5/BBv/cAl4/JAv7@mvke3F/lqZpGzX99dfoL4biX4MtUaXZNuwBivliegWk3ZXNzWgabmsC5ocQ430WZPTcg/cA4muKzx/2dRgM8va/UTAIx0SwMNx0JikM7mnl7j//5p//PnlEcdH516ZA5kLneOhlDP4@RMcPsd1PihsP/UNkHR9/9t2Pv/@PP/7sdz7@7Nexr1DXNjM7Gejxb57ThoCFO4TDgOt3CQcBdRyvsiW2JOXBsLSFM7GSnn79GnK/BCYYiK1IhVWwSXqVzDqaIWIabIxP1aXxDf/S2iZDC7iMyBW@LA1eD9OsUqmkpVEFJ/YwKFgxzohVizh7hHMlFYCLkXicTKMIYxw2ekhQIGYl/Zw1ViojHjGNDlWCgHQlodNzWc/L6WLlESRYGT1iCAuBp6XX8H1dqRYroyqC@0BZABjph5AkhKpg7kbVD2CvEEwIL40efYCsFCvpdLUILhUsZJpSyzQoTb1AhaOyp1laTFrCF/eWbj9g7DNZL8p8ehNQyURofKcnoTEgBAf/0/SKKA79h0b6rWB8qKcR4Ye7cf9tdKb4IgDAVVXckgg/VcXcPADvEQeVpmThk@YQAHNpPnvFIgcSYNJSmuo3TRZIH/LwyQ@A3KpKvEDLy8sSWuVVuXEIg0sYxXlnJT8wPFw0JQmzxOT1TRmdcYdXWEDcCLh8RGPRlUcr8Nbhf2@Jdm1Tmcor0nISZ06STKT6WZr/HjxYYZ8BDug7cZOYml5119wEL@5WOi3nIeGqC7YVKmqaAOE8BP2npVcJiSWIBqDRZPgbPlqF3BkM00V@yeFVRcKc5Vd1tOM86nA4xBialtEyGfHV6EsOmjBo5Cu@2jJJkvyYZw9PdITzDZsSHyoxfX2NjvPQ3YgplpISpoUiGpOe@p2H7giGKBlZzujruPKWEtM9J6U8tmJpr5SD97fdUqnyQV/bkOBL9iHe0ShOTQI9dS3P0ra2kC6qlypNcKERZNt1qVoV@w@YLlWP904g@Mkh0/M5jcHw5nJtI79WWCvkV9fXCxt5fW19c229UFwFjrueK@Tz@uba2mZxc@NqPnd6kMnIG@vyVvUfXXv@h38075nvio9U/ZqNNFxSUK@kaq/Ct8Qu47YE@TQnl2nejVC6XMtl8C@/ugpvyHJGL2zUl5Z6lypi4JT2YV7ixg/ItXSpMhgN3oOHSfckdg@c4IE0cGGWia00B4dlsW0Cr5zmWydkvQCUDlVyCqTOwUmD@FOesg2AEi4vL2M/KbH0ne8ErFqFgYx6sC8loA13WbiLQLVbWleji5FbQ88i3w5jLfsrG29/0Vq2P@gZY6DQnCYlrq6u2tEKF1ktCRlnC@NdmeTSBPPVyJD@/@fv@8nn1fyquqqr@ir@32LI4//dw@fhP49viLWal7a42qMqXovqGq1KdHU4U1KXrUrLNelwV7ldqdU1PDBebmlNtzXW/GAMg2tBNpVks@eaZ8nQ08b71PC0ZiVrZLVGA@gucGHETWP07fxGobSU9bIabnxX2iy1nV/fAJdTJ3QClwK6vJp22iy1tDBHT6GFQLx8Kb9euNoSWhGrUB7MVxVzcSkyV3Jcx7rCzc4low2c89Lkm4RKcr5QlMu18sQOzKVcv3rQt1q2wU5zeLbucm7E9XX5KgwHSeN4HWdUmNLHO5BwF30pd5pLLYicg8iQZcqptCVULVVp20cNWGAdb4Kt1bdCJUxV6cOHDyPaaVU6cAKx5Sq/VkR3JuEEwX0QtO7r3FhYnxhzaDxBhVnPoO6AcTvsCZ6cCFx24vId@g8tc0GI3a5BF@Pueq7v/wphHhrOGfd6ZHNFPZHXYwP1//t9O@guCPFi0Mej/pb3DwZhr9@EDCJN8QAP4eX1XHdegA324mhBKZ9GivZwdxZp2oPgzw8@f3wS@57s7ew@ltbZw8Nnj2Y@BRGowJ7s7Z9E1g3uG0YtRCC@vffkyaxVfEBKKNNU1hIrbODu7NACvbwRGLJcY6N6OQF4Ca5AqC63nOG2fv@@fuTh8Yd1tlYtrm7kSqXTXPkKilR5eFYa4D5v3xqs@NW90cDfXINSsiF7AXi/KKO@GFmGtri/s4tNL5usJKE1kEYhlKlUtkxySjlRlJ7ixvBNnZ9ytH2Jjhrj9at41XIgoTaflnvh0AHOZm9oseGALXSEDzqh0bM73YAFF24YQGoaBoPfpz4Q34o/wc0OAU@D3K759OYEx31IdpvlJI1wkt8sFoqbq/liprhZXCvo64VCRs9n9I3ixibIGzm9qK8XC5t6pri2uboG8hH4FjY3pATICXY7mwWhVJdl@JYArGPiFWJbeBebq3WrUoJPNrN3ipFiCSOyD5lsQRwZ7671Azr7smJX5PwaHkwDIRUgGsxkif393dz@viw/RAsuhe3mZLmFlkIxl9t4KMsW@eyCDJeXZZfHKaKyATngllzu4a4sDzkA1AUoy1207K3jyFmWbbTs7uzvYzpttOQxPgQ74z7c0gstGxDMQcvqKg29ZfltBA7C7fCE1iine2jBNNFnn/vsgp8sfx7mJ5cDCM95OA7hcVjWnR1ZPuCWnR302aWCF3hWv0TLDj2y7IEFiFCWO2DoYH8gy00wIinKsgkmc2yAG17XhurgHGyEY44gRJEsjyi0YZ7JMEAU7pjM48ePjW7Qsjr8GXv8C83tAHzs0XBvv/n5581Op@mNd/Y@f44@u7uPjfZ46DU7TRGt2YDHhTjgc9Yfzz6Qx4NGw@jN9fkSfJwZn8a4YWHeGsZbyJN4OphIv7ELPrvgM2@unkODpw9Bm/g87MP3odEkn/AhH/qOmk25jISK@hhwZh3bzJkDvCDTN0zPLaN9VFliSSWZGdfWc/UyubO@wlKXwL7Qv63QDeA4qAIJ@3JcG1Vy9cqospEXB@gU@XSUL9hyZqm/rW@CdGJs6/m19KiEN0a47SRLqvq2ot9feac8A0Fkda0kn25vq3JNr2/n9WJpfePVylCWUyV8b69ulN7BOCsJgyl8pWob9W0QeSZRNjbSRjZf2tjAMVj5CjASQJfUHAZWo6EoF5ZxlkphjrGjBzGMisvGVFS73FZGmVGFZ4yNIf6oope5fiKWuwasharxhnjbLgfZURADo@1cCVc4FFnfLMqQhWxWSaWQMSErge/rl@EybPSJGaaM/NFYSeWXdevF9ZSGJ7IabrtBF5ay1/GQk10R0ks8REkKFMK9zjT690vSCY4xsUcg8cpuApfh2rVG0ohrwGJ8QlLf2JSkqhhXHfEbFMvC@vnjXQ2GWsKGyva0fRRvXU/bRbY35cMVwYVOJ9DbaY8t3MFshm67XLWBtjeCITXKyKFHqDRJE2prtJPH5Uu1gasi3zo5Ozn5Wr2Kgz2GMSbPCB4BK5MiI1SmgKoJ7RYzKlUwGShMUi4BBakLQkejWq00Kn2rPwjGUOYw3pe8n50AOvB5YaKjaRT9Eo9rCo9GJXc1Cf9s2GcPeSA60xlGa1QeAn5zZQc1/VpoXWajxEiqtlBv4cPKw8thCQXSq7JVsTzP9eQEHoTddipDxzfa1pHl4RnMg8Nl1mYWnnY0u69P9zDkLkrWV2rVY85UPhRDrTZT004xK6JO@VaEkUs6RYALeVcwQFFepcpvweYtM6WlPUxtr5VbykPWSIFL7nX7dZvl2fpamS7HURAScATCHGLESFWqXwJgDvesVIKMCJI4A5iY0DLUiN0iHyM1sK/KnUoNQ7/H15Yqy3VVrb2vS9WyVAUGUx4njIo/bPJbr3NNPZ9bL4/ATd9YK3dZs9J8NSp7lQGMxlm5B9UupiD40QgDt8kDkgDOu/fKx1/7LkttqYUKdywTsPc9ECYaWqMymtTQaqWWX1vP5NfXcMZifRV@eia/msedv5l8bjOT10GmAFkD4sNvA@xr8IMwIHLkdZzXUHqKzJicyY1ymp7RLT2j5F7brdepzBlOLIFUSEhLZQJ3zwHKAQckICBbssLXSKXzKz2l5TJjSyUaBqZXpoIamS4b2JkugnluGT0ePKWy1RWlt6xgmOWT4WCvVi@VQMz8Fnop6tvt9fRGLv0ulSorSyxV8a23hGXkj4SFwRJQtJiuYf6wX8stQbmhDapXUNvBsr6RL9WGyzVVhwLm3ne25Kpch@q6YhL8xVeKQewqg1vIB7mgNhG1Jm4DFLB7FlStvpkviyDSQDBmRVZO5fAkj5JMbuSTyVSyjLOYS@AuGDux4CT0Csn7@rYMop5ckjfzMvD0CT@/lgU@z7euS4krCUe4bG1TSlxKV5dXW/FNjV@y8dgAwVs89xnrpJcllqWdPFojwZbIpGpVmm7eqex0nu@UReidXSlRoh24k/2R7FToYmBqdulT9w@lt6qv@PcUd@NBshIpt6qxOm0HsGxSC/wVHk3bZkkol@H1a/n8ar2W34A@HRhxGDSfh6L7lxJHON91lt1KV1n2VJJlYkF8d0KxkOKlYB8S1OjZ7mU4vVGi6xmYYpR4I6/VUx@e2b3L4qrKx@FK4sNyOss02tjZyH5IQCd5leA7wvPXdoRDXsIdvl@@zheguhw3dICBeABsH7raQkGm@djXjA2ON19tvCq@evri8MXhPk5slvTkFo7b3i@5Bf3BUi5XKpaKZVZmH5wvvsUGydW1JJTktJIYVdbE4Q29WlX1rTzbBqplJeD2bX1dzb2vchKsksd6Hnw@/tpP10ZbRbDnQWAuAQoL6Xy1qq/kU4nBx2/@NR7evdz7aucJS6Iqlb/789/Pb/zdn/9L2tqRvCr7NC@4kYCQaNTXNxKXl4PLyyt4uF8hUU/wPK1tpMDMt93oiWo2ITbG6Bt6KuGrwqpvFBL@exEln8Ot/@C7e8gd5PUCtIHE3nO7kNcfbCHK9QjlLPrbsvzNhJQoPn39njGwmNVWp2PnyZTNstIHdQv/Gc5Qf1CX2OtKFRfC2CZ4RtOkK9VqdYWck9U0nk3PF8CzdlWupxnNs1rWK8tacVZOp2aiTx1wsvwV/CNvsq/4PlhDm7XyxodMskIVRt0r2Wz2NPXx1347n1//uz//zfeN942vgSdvbm6u6/nELyBLN5wdDUdtNPGDp0DREI322IL7fDVTlhJ4yXOb8fDh2A9He6g5geudQpt07tpCuVAD0GeAqK1QsBU8AZchoZuOy6fKkhRJpiRUex0zQzDYCqowh4YkXUr30Av6M1YBFibdm4AChz4qrDIbfm/oDUg@VCieXs@w@xAFUriHKk6W6OSe4IOqXmbZletReZa5tiOSQFjf8n3UcQZ8WroHUZ4ADdOFamxg4OlPDGk7wHg1DEL5JI9WDdKuQ9o9HqFBrgqVngfIMJ47HskBoVu6h0fZSCqHbprZWxCgzFLSPUAAlEERgO0622KrKXZpp9PliVK0K9y2iBoxjPBsmYTREFoLD1SGkcsYzuaKT4YeKgNjooZNK@4YAuEw@DJaBcYLGJ1sKObQ8dE7gwJYpEZAoaKx@/cnuapU7FaKUYkQPmqEQ0VuEw1W1xIAYOFg67NWSc4wJ53Gyr43TXaA8TRlF6hOJcMkUBsP@aH1SpLg/85EixQ5U1XkUcYCiPrircIElEFkRDuvQxN12un5jRSLMm9C3k3KFCnHiUaQp6PPNNJRZfIsXkm/SITqfoG/nMTHOYJuZw8XMuilhqiIFTUncGYgjg3ye6OQTx0EYewoFhTF7lHotu3BiIEW/0I1O8qqnsJo7ciF8kFcOb/GcCdhIYUfioWhURmLgYpNRDpLNLdNGuH8geuQJhQ6VY77LUk/nS9xvS8820PnwiCdZjwV2p4YyxFXFIeUT3rMHK6szedxcaGRXxQgcJNhVkcjlT/5TaZw1YM4FelE4FIUiTIM40QDcdzsWX3I0rFlMdTG4Zey2Q5IGMMmqd94agNddfdt6C0cPytusste2Gd29gSViKpuG8RWcdwzgUKJHWnCEjouSJFdzz6z@PBVmTqv67P8egbEwgxgdvIDxJawg8czuTnwzvBQ8NuAzwY3FjOxuEvKOHX9u6ovKQ2s0fdcp5SHt9WdG04Mv/S8l8Sg0x/74WF8Oh0Kdi1iudAy@Qm8JB7Bi46KSkJrQIVOtGs4Yz5QQLYKz5CiESRR6xxCqLqEfQwwTTM83IqtGEp7jzoAanvQslBbTeCV8NR3BfW4KSY0PcHgHfYZW81LpNWP9CAItQUAA6u@Mg0d/CAqlsMPWlAxGp95AL4CrbPfAr8EKm/i5IfxQ@pGM2lumpA3WxLgsNOhtCqMN4vQUohZsHVwPXxQ9CXwXIcczsnJkiKnAWxaTskcdBR/Njqndol4SYldh5RhCEGgGqCgqPDQ8LmicaFq5uLiQiNtR0PP1iwflUv7eAtndtCxQQZ1s4HVH4grgmy8KU7cgjkxqVylPN7Xuj2ia1I374/5V5LaeP767dD2LCXZ9pPYB56jHuROn1RJoJIHn@hm3yYV66ZC68y@ILN8PXMZklkJyUwtJq8QCGMIZpQZZ8wMAMs0zbNM@6JVFh78gnEADpVlhY6oiNALLX0/NNmDdhTCDWjnc2hv9s5Mt@ei6CHzCdZJ0ryEYchxaBX2gT2CSI51wXY8zxgr5J/C0EinypikGzaG3p18wAi9Cbvk@rrsUW1cn4o@iqJD3xWts3qoSEK6vBkoV5OG/iPuPwL/EfcfTRINk62N6lzyQqcrLA4SN@qFCkMimHEY5opreZv4EGQQkZnOQWDI8ZTbFfzMCsUO8c1tUI@VkDCAJki5ooJaHWundce3Llbq6WwHaFomRECNA@hanXB60YrMiP3eeW/g@lNODqpNgs5H5BudzK6gBk4rWMaogogwOL5s1K7T6Wt8joX3@6LAAAHFLfBECWAnUOxUOdJqS55AODV5gmOesZrITJ2ELOEl3EAq4qjniI0DqscAoXtUJMgm@LCw5YgLAwQTeOnhrc1hWJUuACD1vMl6EjA501Q4SylTJcVypaphNgHtKJVWZosS@kNV1Ga8YsW8EvUfz/7SJ2e/De1ifu6JYHm/UJbiTcUaoTJSSzQXwiqrVmL1CjnIrhg9y4MOao@LoaJThmRWsuFogqeDReBKdJVY5ZspXj90qER25FJECuNKBYo4rvBmydtFiFKO8CiaL6KNQ0IQ8TkDARi5udEsEW0UjzaqVDjjYKMF0S5imRxRJkc8Cg89WpDJuogGg6RITStWTx2184FAJQM8nfeWqIlWZr5xjuqG2RvUpgODpzDNCc8hKhA0hJI00plZn5t6LZbpGNOaAYCEeA1Ai99RVJJmGZ6uRraIR3FUhjyK2wQZcF4BBEYsuMw1pikRkdFQF@R6OU39ALRdOV2TZB03gdFfjv/kTOgY/vTrjrnpkPq0Yy4z8/cP4lhHzMYaaEzI0HNryJBxwLJDCmRALLlwmTJHeAb3bHi/dbbZc5vZvoGbK7Je7NbrVDgeIBWRDwZuYATu2lqJD4Jsoq8XIjiL3RLCxwB2x3FhqBHXyGhzDZJOEhVlmm7HsX0rg/dscxHcol0A/OYVKS73CqPrS5KYAuTDUgTNCQhF10YDb1ZrNBTf6rVTpUjdKVo1pMNkUsLxLJhi8YEPCaCHA8VtvrHMIHU7TFRXKqKd2OaZcjgQnklIZIcBszJBngffLogqzHcnI0HSI4iicTNQ6BqYrtt3OyDeoY5QjD0D/mACGzNkDAaUlwwzcIhaiil1peagmBkjJaJ@@clR2Zd5xUhF8fPTAKaQkWHeLI4Rs96c5BoLk@PRwvSOPz2/x/H8Ht@cXxpVz@aZD7Ur3PPTkl5VJhAg4CQbq7dnIyNUcl/LzlRWImcUoHiEO2exRZuXWpjTHQi6I4JrbaCPTGTzSVGQyPhXi/B/cwWG0ffuWn0GXjR5PAZ@08c9cgrdvOSHy4MKBD9IIe@5nlxE2o/umBaExVs89lFWAHmVGJeDWqigYQ5gGO3L0cqIAHwLzeP2pGt0T3uWKtxzTp688ww7yy@uokeNltUzxlZLESEzMbhhiZ/DyIz41d0KjoyOmJ7LB3UKdFKpuAprRDoPVFpAMkbmPKbA/FoYHsSOqIdmvimHB4vxh/7XWDNO2VX47DMI/MlkgnTd09UEg/FgzLV39kgJcMhHef/DaxKP1t6OEMCD2NmQmSSbuol9PleiIt2hR4jCatNFJj1dYbfl9gfX6/DTUHR7SaFyY5EqYS1P6RdfVOP2TTUeo4qQJvlSz91I8jaiuzPNxUiNA5uwsN1P60KuQcYdDaapxCFylxtrzHWu8QR0o3k3Z0Gv0pjDUKOYxOkCm8bVJF@kJBwCH8AXJ5C@gi8C7FhBgxNUWDacoxI32THy6RuDmNQiXEAaBygxLIa3SFA2YqGk0AzBL6@iNM2FaZrX0jSn0oxawHSSsUCSOZWkqAWsnpuqoGe1gwXcGb1wkAyfm9g2PI5reDgtcZm0kyU7w5LnyRIw5KSVLO0pwJSTrWTpERn8ZOmYDGfJ0pdgmLSt5PtkKWwWGMADKxkeoLtg4Wg3k6VdJXUlBXjRR5iulixFdQphtrmVMAKowHKD1IhLZo4rihl4FnRsJFRmGFKMn8FxEk24ZOiXg3@u0Z/fPAOeOGe5QoFZmulTnUasx@DpQLcR6nqd05JLojffO9ynHUGTKxPAPw2DuXgcAg9ieCI5zYx4xtCXVijgCxlEvlmanyOmT9@rcYfsiNSBQqmSp9Mn7GkkD7QU8q9B4Hpq@roGET@sr2kQvALvlk@MvCif17ITJkc5wjXW1JxsIVJfJ28oFNb1zF0kvPbjNURz19OB8B7WMAivJQIb4@kgw9FiGyY2cAfTREK@uM/Pjseh2TfeKJF6Z6IRVxAtc4E3OYuSIWOIN/7UTcWJxcOsTbEg9Kzl6ryVRf0C8WL0mvC6mKTKGx9kIcZzoIVb5pmFZPtIGCkcZzcZ6isWdUNhXJ4kca5pNgmRNdQRMjQCnno0eN1DzSGfNnwNY45wUkVBALGYUSqcv7qfIL@7XH4PBeoQCTMJzBOs53el18XrG3vZmZz3Jsler0D0zLBHqbnCUZTCBOUwOohJ5jfR2jURH7dwcCGfJxpBn5H2Q7RFY4Jb8DY7tuCwUErwzqcdz/LgeJZfjKjrEknvXAuFFg1TEnB4waOcTop2c155wedVMfrQRLbR@@QK9qYrOF55CI8K4M2gnLdyPLaJa1uTtk2KdNEFWapeYpyR0/JnVM0TR2D3tBQbLcOCw2Hj@aPDZ0@@DZ3uxsZGSvTR40n@sNXipGrUj3PItBs56g/mDFvyGVQkj4vXdG8w3mm8dOrI13gJZ9YgDOAFOiH5iTaeErwsxs9n2i7E42FjGBWwzibNwJjiSijqGNhl2wKvASDECpQVQwAJxVvAd4ZGaymckwXqwLv4Gg3qvhoN3IzUaIheDKsmXOFO/SKxlB36Hl0Py9VcX0gSnb9mjw7Zy8c7J@zk8R7bf7H7Jfv24Qv2cufZCZ5XPnrx8MnBLoPf3rPjPTaZUcAHr/7AASXg9ZFlWv0mXiOby60xgrzrDsac7yi7Ke5@bPTZY9e0cD1qyzf6D7rcojlWUOWx9mA4OsY5TJtul@nbQcCvzTMBHAk3LTq2htv6GYRtwpi2j2Pevtuy2zaElXDsO7AtPzxYxXo21CDw2/DEZIYLSXgNCW0Foivo6PZAvH4OwuMiDYAx/Ml1h7bPI1gtjQnERc8nY/Bk7/nTY7bz7BHbPXz26ODk4PDZMds/fA7Wo28fPPsc8HlwfPL84OEL9KKATw8fHewf7O6QA89ATmN4Ip3uE7wpCxoGJ6yYZ7jETddER7b4rDMEAwmeXRh0gM9nyaGD3Mc2evY7q5UsS3hBET80SGsCLLoekFlvcSkzXPOl/QTyC5@u2FnOsS1KDRpLFdpbWTRX6PZQ2TkuPPTHDK9assp0Olwh8@QKJ9qU07ItJu/inhOc@@aHyKkth6AhoSWAjaDCDSgVRjcHJJOZLQJZhdTMnota0nhqfFOgsGDUB@HWkbJEGBN7XxAo7vU/cHA@SC9HDkD34JAXyQYeD8BWIwcegK1xBxRFD3AvCCuIEMPgcIjsma1zhzf9wT6t/7KNyOGhQaPYosgTrzeqUoNNLp23@4Me3f3AZ3noSifDN22bovgUHu9O6PXCexWbFpA88ERxCxbuVYOQMjCbNi41iG1szpAaNvgCNeC@H6Md@EyppDR2gpt9LMfml2p0eobDtzRNtuIQ7bEiahGpiE3ZdnRbBZ2eGLhEgHiDzHQ@oniPhFRo3TUexHx4LUVD7HmkG4/CLWW3ZeDhtQz8MmAAkDo10jGpp6IjnAjGbQtSVnwXKBLnbT/EwwM5t4amNRUhvPXyjf3uXUogOTM1Tgr3HVLuoIrwgtAMX7Nsux60cWKrfTyLglzQ7LqDwOZ1qEyXYHJnGYTGjg1Se12pTqVG95TOpOi4TizRJlDxglSbQJR3SZUoni@SR@wrbOvRpWm0jw6zYzTxyuPJ2lkGF5EuLJx@AUGYX/iIvQ1d3yvkT2nCOz7QJZzFSvXRw1P1w@sMXvnA2QK/5izcRMgv7exjWtA8aJ2PNiB6KHeJlhbeG@IPmxhb7KkT3BJbeQgMxoFdG8Z1DxrlyI9vH77ujodMZt3J8f37Co@lImfiHHnod5UJd8uwWphkhuLUmdjrEeOdkFng9UrokiGYEb9@gOdJsBbKgBEH@Qhdtzt9X4dgIWHpmsM2cBZxI5eo7gh@ilVp60QoSNKjxOsj@0p5WElXU9nJzhEWQ6cSsuhMCBkv7JrsP6H@6hq4RzeDA/59d3DFG3PHu4dPgvboRmiflDc1vRgW75ZisO4O9sMNYHnn9kuBhbJnFgPmneR1aBGlR8SZWU5Eu2NvTvH1tbqjtgdgsO/FGZQIaCy1oUNL1KEqU4VHSMXBTASi45NHe8@fM5mPTyAu8D0cMrQEG0TYS/w6E7571naI2WmR0BQNliPhKXSZ2roWPjc15rnIW8AqhAySEfiImMX05aHE9UTPQiIE7aYnhhhibjp3lyEP8msC8BXqrgXmlZiIYVEBpbnFTPDOx/bjm7oF3jJcNo7vyacd07zvxmvAvHEcUHzzj9HBkyLz6@8ll49LYTpcwLLeDqnALZCk8SZcjR1DwgMIqGnTNXhDtYRVipvmuYCdCHGHO7xy0xL2r05QREhcCOeycIytC@FYZI3Lx8uhmEM7D7EbMHBLp/DkO5TBI2Tx5LIVr9DUpNNTprsgEDLxgqoHcaqA6PWrcnSnrTLpJyuRQB5va8uUm1qYyzrOzgrY5cWBPsO9zeuz7GE2KeC2Nyal/v0kxXuJqZRCnM8tTOgJkNcLhdXbYM@WIoyu/qqweR8yyz@D/gDG9xOQ/tin6X2g3INnmdB/QgA3oI5vlQ8bzExEEHXm9ClTZafOKJ4/yAufF4LMoF5gs4vXcU2nmmKjmbzNh857pDh0CnKtDLEmHBWUt5pr2L@6OTlkyLemt/Tp6fHGhoFwj@DVL6LDdTFdKjEnPDM67WZ5nkPB@LGkvovHx@g00o1n5ujQHN/QyguDnrTMFi9AWxwy4ttqM@EUAyVCs4oaXt@Hk3rl2Vk9VS/HS7h/8GSPrZDuufbUFKTsyakYy1mynZsyQKyXpiOw16CjeJ/5JfhBHjIhSEATHcpTCDepW/NGGAFhuUa3Lohtn4Kl6rOV3vZNw0HFHhmZbr6@DxFp8nXvcD81b0I9V56KD5nzB44CsTKyqskUFdxwHhchTYPgtYnusX5KwmsHxAbJGy77NbJ6Mbe@KVHpnEyQ6dc265kVsyIz6HMNp@8PvYvWWcftnrdZjw3eNEfm@N1bxgprbBV1Rt7nKi/19Qoex1YYag0pss0cEazI4DYpFT2VGdNIUSKuJ7PJ8Lu8xFJkoLFyCU9AzFApW@mHVIgn5YJKv7ZerziVXLlfc@plPKsXpCtBWk8r6HAfOk9gLXxBvhbUsSv9RXy21XLOmTdsjmGUFJ39YHT2A/t3nOESe7Zpvpy2GUv3cLManiHRHOtCiS4yR8qUUP6R7tEhHh2PftN0Mc62tGzIAWA/A8KqP6L3OCXdy2nDQeCSj0hIRRJi7@330r3w1FGOJgwgSM2uh9nZIjiTMAqu@3DXMd8NrepcGtPxqGMqBqKGMYnbyaeyjEcAMaPi6FWtLvmaZZhdzAReWfmeorGtLX6X/RV40yQd7tQwPDr4kKujEdc34DOgxQRMggRzn45vSFB8tOto4C40BRXQeRfa6C6RIIg@uI2bXdJxJIq/BQjgiL/HRSpNzGAKwQrkRH7Uj@YOUKHc9LgeVxHwFCSvlHtYWITN06tMgNOOb8IRJivQBO73LhCdHFfwiBKoOtmuFSMKn@LBCSW0DC1sPuKSqpS8qvjpTaIpsWhqGC0MHEPFvVuxgRNZMPp5akHzGbNdq9eDTHNc3JugA410HFekn47S92uYZj3KPPdXr/mrU/4a9@eZmoTSoP@eBCrFA8mJy0m4KyZPgmWupVVhJJtoUNOmBhLHJGz5prC@FrgNexK4GlUlp8rIY2vKQ435vJpT@9xnaSpOROCRf437C/rOi5qPcjkV9sF0@viVRAVZtDdWbCWZoVLNsXvbvHOKfJDMZMAmYzw61jeRHW@U4sikYCcgoOE0PjXbamUCJa2HHIfajFzdeiBrQpjYVmazwQ8dXmtYc9pIDEuUZpoQN6LzhZAOeS/FQBBMJDQWttxqGHksIo9jYDHUUpgsP7R4rYFD0WabeAWPMb7HV9jYpzMXhkvM97zHcz7iheeHkacRREx3SZ6Ppmlugsc@uKMo1A29yCTt8SzE@UziWWySN0rT4kem2zjLvRTxiTijCDnFNbxHPgLTkwB6SL6LqhA9r6RfZFekzw0QoQc9a8R2cBRh0Gkqaeo8OupY9VH5Ealh8YeDQQ8XFUmwu6ATz0JxR76AqykTiLFlNE06wI07PHwGTeL8OETS2CFCvsD9HxMPf9jBi7Rx3QZ1HgFrxQkVO9CkHWfM5yugzazm@alwiw19vigKg/lOPBO85njrQUz7A8O0NAlkMR@kHIkXtc3bt5gux2MhqH4LurSSJH1raJtnu5/jcu2GnlvVYyg7F6u9OW11bXJQCpAUeuRzIK4W9DVJii39mnzpV0WAGfYEO/qvgDatc7yuWdqBHoMC@iCc@pZ3brU0SXpuRWu8CBdJGRce8di0O/RMPncDshVe84ynff0MX@0CCsMv9s98NdikpbCMhGtSk8VkqOpzu4UIDA@UtF1c/KX1CDzVz/GBkfpWAEhZSbHpLNHSssgLyS59nGcCbKBaktjSQ4QGxw1sE2qGJqqkHoDiqxyTxPil9LGcQHpmz8BDvtq8DODplwkGwgyEK0U35UESa@KflAcmChYuoRthzWSB@7nUVqC5W54N3HeCYKoVihbLO1TwyeODY3Z8uH/ycuf5HgPz0fPDrw4e7T1iD79NS9i4Dk5KX9njwyfAXaLFcr4ofggO8s4xxJTJQ/p/23uy7DaS5L6FU6QKElFFYhdXgWA3SIIttClRw0WLSQ5YAAogukEAgwJFQGr6PfvDF/ABfBR/@Cg@iB1bZmWBoMhePN0zb/q9FgtVuURGRkZGREZEVt58VNUPbw@rR0fq4FDVXr/dr0Fr0Pxh5c1xrXqUVrU3O/snu3S4Di2oNwfHar/2unYMxY4P0tSrrpaI6qmDPfW6erjzCn5Wtmv7teOP1ONe7fgNdoaH9hX1tnJ4XNs52a8cqrcnh28PjqoKB5bYrR3t7Fdqr6u7Wegf@lTVd9U3x@roVWV/f2agB@/fVA8V@QBYo9yuApSVbVBVsSca527tsLpzjAOKnnYAeQDgflodva3u1PCh@qEKw6kcfkxLo0fVP51AIfiodiuvK9/B4BLuA1iBedk5Oay@RqABE0cn20fHteOT46r67uBgl3B9VD18V9upHpVUYv/giBB2clRNK7xairqGNgBb8B2et0@OaoS32ptj2DNO3qI7gweT/B4QA1BWoOouIRi9HHC0gKSDw4/YKuKBJiCt3r@qwvtDxClhq4JYQIeJnWO7GHQISDy2h6neVL/br31XfbNTxc8H2Mz72lHVgwmrHWGBGvpbfATSgU5PaNQ4TwAXPwKxJjTlpmk6VW1PVXbf1RByKQ0UcFQTaiG07bwSnMNaziUsY0l3gLYB/8o2oLTvvvoUYLLGu5aX@bYYk@Bo52C3CjuypI9yog8nsOusz2Q@sr/BTmM@ws9YhplW0Lju1Lv99gBjRU01NnBchZ003q7hgXquzhJfuWBF7ChUIZms199V6qDoHtXrXvoxNWNgPFRDrNxfK@XJGDH3O2reaOB5@ZLxvhlD1NaCnGOSHx6eL2BJxv4Ce7b5V4GncrlWINUwCB8b1iaikE9FLvGkBFgjxTLivRJRl2SBoN9dIQeq6Orms806mkHR8ZEKDUL4p/9T9IM3B@sFcGc2a@VyqMQSGN3Pge6GO6HUBvSPZBbotqnLbBgEP3bcvN0d6vzZzmDQcj1P16GyY9ADO673QPVG0JmpnpmtT8DSqbKkjA@13k0ijDleFpQpmZfsiEbm4j/1Mf3xNDScuwGNotQV2aLFOOkucHV0OEorSVGB0RM0ySjzva58qL1HbS5fXC7NvH9l3vPaQndATDcLG94p1TunP6/OuQAsMMqpASjpSqaLXM6qo91JTOEbKHiJhSinPu3VlwHt64ASEGSv/Z7dJ@7Go@7Ehh748HeHldfbJ3t7wDoR2uX1lbXVUsJkyfqQ5r8fsR9KgkpJwoawj4OcRp@sVbIDgg@tFCtzdkT@RMC5HBbE3OR60ugl5mswbhlxRyVkZDjcEC9Z6aMHnhMgHhxFiTSeJjS9zl2ZQgBubKgejubKn5CI74OsRDQgviq9Kc3aBP/Bts3y10vcDEgISEiMUs8C5YJ2QXzP2dOeoKTcUJ4dLJJ1NB1z1jWDAzJ1kXssBs/SL6FtaxZD9lTE9UrTTjUBiKezUCjtNtHnlf2W8oWIoZeSfcGbD0Jv8PhR8tFRdjo/HFfGR4DGPVMT7dGR0VkGfSotn2@VYYoWFkxPmwqt@Z4ARWtPzMYmwYe1GgiUc/QZLKuZhksmH8hsl@Tg@m3KU1@YUjEJB7ZTEoqV30C584YjrZR0HhD5rbNLKG7LJCthrN2YPhK6yEeTj0KjM4amX4UPav93xMmc9jdB44TWI2xZOfsehUlqlXEF6ishpXujDxSsU4wIm/arj1Ezt/bEXJqBySnNhMNnAAUyO1P94iNlKWy7cxCARI6GDXv9Go@zSx9Up28dT6rjeUi/eTV0lewVequ4025m9TxNYldan6HgD095bGuyOtyHqupbVtwatOpBZZpR5dXz0OHmPJ3HI7dIBhCz4IlKL9kpdZay8rLKNB@QlEnWhtMymY9ALL2993RuUVkZLWO8X064NKKg6S2E5@44KVX5QLH3bTxBIqdGP6akdZgtG9Vk3Hwkw1yD/Cx7AbbzvEXGELwYdnyDG0SPW6fMelFryn1OfiDYSeRUGKUFRHbrZQG1tK3eGOjJMokUaqA/6XPO@YCtWrpElvN3CIR2NHxWvfanAHLvccNmEsstHg3S6JqInbFZQurjJbjNwWAEoqOP4wYY092pl1XvxegQ9MPrkaQbhP2sOxKLhBb6oRsUm1h7p22G05sTaGF3jMEIrSzRBw3pKkAHUM4@MsmsKheIV9PoljY6didLBeVuRl82ASeURZSQuKlW1U8/cSlGqGT4DAiD3dAoF@SSSf3guYNZfjeD0Y@496MI1G8FLZNI1GqSbIE8SbU@pWRsjnnow0FIFg2YCrSAGEwU2JBm/FBhj14TchK3JSdKZompRmkkP78fQ6TaGQo6ighXegfiW83AZCKWipLJ0@T2LBRXCJR5CtftvcoYJfeMH08r56xvWMpLFiLKz7XoiE/MN83TR3wSI3/5eYirB97gWbaIoAgwyqx4fnqXzxF8mJjvfTcYtWybKEgyLX@I5jdSfQZ9okVtOpT0fU1/HAZT0ACaue4kR23U3e8Hl/36zqDnd7qDrg96GuY5nzDHw8cpPeKEdUaDm5Cux6EPLatQaxo9c/oYTqeGv825ZMlKsRWOg6FruyOMR9PKJWeBIMs5@vgps18RfQ9nc52ZOssrUaVEPLyU3O0KXuneui8K8yrzyT02IAxua8ZTgkNExxR3ZMWWlu4UaHytgAVjQ2WU793jkBeDeANQRMcwMYg1MHfcD@xBoGZ2L8SnrUm6RbkER5hHKdgN8IKZ0KXXaR8vUgUu8g16BLxUhfW8VZVPUSaYTxAfpveju7j2O0MPAPwK8Asv5lHLPEIgFtfWyZRC1lckKSjAQt5/XeLRxImBi3U7sAv1Yo3WJ7Otxj9P78MGefiAUCTp8u5QJa5IFxQfvFbNrQPLqU893FRSKuVRWg4UQSpjN38/wQYPucfS4sdDXLacIWPakZZdC@j7UNUELOEVmTPeszbInAL54RVTLD521mYQWJ7nUWZd4@A6WnKhAJMu7694rDUYATN2ZrAnrh6pcDwYph6JvXt5x9wMa/Nw3fS8B/18mdjKsFkutgi15Sk@TkuJWXhmiCaOMfIoAxpC9ZWeDZnPInFSruN6K9enD@DhPpxF/lFmUzHz3eK1j5viJ3TY1RuNWVIEOyYbLZn3p3UYeP1@DiJtsnpVJ45RR5ZRn/Kj1dQMmgyWHo8hoj6BfQYfLcAc9tsC3Nnzcy9SZ53hdOpS/SmWrBLxiXnWMSYT@NKwjc4XmAWOJVzDpIzAOUlP6SivkGlgsmD8wA2iVBxkIjsUW3CjyZqhI0rm33br6C1UQE4ET1u2h4PJ0W8QRkn0xbgjHg/1aaZwXuKWJqYl0Cqo1Nda0uHk8PO0PqFW7qAClvgcVJgR3eFNl48f1a8dC5SDFrg2fRZH3nwaB@OpJYAG/rE/1ScoA0ddSc3YioovhDqxBlgLoKV0egGrqyj9dUdM8ejdIMsIFAh@7eKfJamB2bdX8wbbWGXSmmIRT9DNq81TmS2uEhEU/0b0y1JkUZcUV2ggYIihfrkALWB6UoIeDwUos45NeTFAZY6gYrmAyxJeUnbTyJ9zzndEqhRYXrFK5OeV2LDbyMxtBASL@WUiQEBmmV8kagU2urmwWCXW5o8nKgECsaZ9xjhMhcxKHIdm5hiB8EjQGo5yWlDpvFAwfVxe8WIfDX3T14289TU/@xXwYyA8zRRmv67nY19j3RaL8aqxmoAPz@419hFQ4dkAG67w6/6jyBM7dbnxCbWUjJiUIX7YfVSlblBvy/4Qqk2KudYyhm7PDvzW6ledb0SJJVf/eiJ1JWn6S79@sNoxVQMimf0p65wOZXFZHySB1cGdHkeFiq7Oo2fSD2iVdtBW74739mJJXRtT7Wd0FYxW8vk80nDDzmGvXajRktQd5OKlc@3rXi83vPl@9K6RI9aPF9H3wsFLrUAHMCOwJsLsYNThexwQBiiKpTMSpoqq/nW7bV@YgAeUOHcwa1xSch0o2n@6xufl3THZf6hJ2V8vcIA4vgtlFt@Nz3KmtKJPoaA2egR/cvThGaAHX7TRDdscVFFjyJe1MxNsW1556wtuIHgPCU0WZSH2vkTeyc6roNcbpNX7wajXwjwAT25nK@zt2RXyXAQPGCl29zqkbLNpFXzq9qyoYSxikzo2p/clfSuETu@OKe4Pg051MnSd0z87sKvAkJdwmEuYZjqtnI7jSc73RzTLdAhgP6r0lT90m4Sn2cKw08sCjp4AoheF9FzVJ1bEI5OY4Ozh0ojU@eBmKRUDDN0jUUCnpKfppZHcU9wg1zmbFNqIwzy3ITBhRpXH1cBAst@PK34at9uPY4qUzZ8n9q/OEOkIgFagLD/AJybD/qcMLOu9mXQhLN/gnRt3@Q5WqGOFROJ5s/yXG7dSqahnw6UlValsw0MmoyrbFbWLL7a31S783sbfC@XiykqJee6u9wVebuuXt2ob2iAD51LzcrQLP@FbGaPC0Fkbp/hZrvwsXXpWL29ulcLcaWUbg/bh6X/@9d//59/@I1eRH/@JP7bpx@mfTaFsNpt71vzybOG2hL9Pd89Tzxqnz4bnqU4JqQzZ/cko9Hu@5T2abSYeiJBq9bqN@6KmjPdMNyRXTXSXdOGfchk0sJ9@4qezcfQ4ih4xJ2pU3e8NL32qrqiFrXKqklpYgKfNcuqfU2Q7kfe@ef8Z3isPeTklTSDU4r0/qnK0U6vZaceR65P03g4wRw5eYCn5cuTg6iKpr/nLnKpsVp1n1IUBD9086lwwDiKrmQzMvwiQenTkk0Nn16I24KE0mb7ZHM8HU1dhh@Q7bTrny8980VSet17yGRq1sQQMD8uX2Fdd4l5x@AAuHnuVM6eF1ZXzTDKZTJgL0epNYnPU25D6Mhdk6SN0ys/AYVhDWDIwdrqgroy4gAYRGckkXZe10ORr3dw@qtakMbHCnUxZ8jzam2ggCcPm2MLNyRRQxkKFj64gU@E1RWGgbDB97BkeAEDhdZvEuBTfgBwOg2a3PTUuD3gjRdQ77JUYMreo2nci5pQzajgyrqftqEFACEoBlKsHG51tkJE3gLJd4nY8Rv0bxI27RHUhyb/VMk2wcQgaDnrTTg86c8mVKrwB7gSY92Syen0dSoc9cM1GAFJPICuaJyzy5UW4GwGaIvpNPCHD@6F6mJOLBT4@/qVslLAeUMKR@@HaGAri9vrsQDRowyNs@BhFx0dYRIZLuKUKQaFSi8qxvl9O@MDi0PPUkEsiVuF3dPhO5EEmSNKH5aI7SRPCpzFDT2ri202htCFe7YeKtOQG9WQlObRWzOkbSJVXeFaJ55SAFCyZpbvEgDVM1UWvf2HGz6ebIV5HmHV0l9xNkf0TgGOZbnS4PHXHsQAOG1fp5jE84ZRLsAdh2G0AsmCIMk2UApGDB0bQ6lkqwZ0JteBxICIYXy0OzYqyx6dJKZgMKT6f4X2Cpt2@poJYQTwgxTOxAM/uMMfBQFge/OoP@hliuY1g3G2yAyX3/lTz4iGei9MxJQF2f0egPPg4TjPB1MOZzi4kx8U01VE7hCcMVsD1f2lEb59wJmZeYdESOAIAGeIws3MWISlq0VACNRBHisBI/t@CwScxwuwFne44VictGRjY7ZxHcatRj4v8AgG2sTuDWQyU0CfNhiVcCL61awYyXv0NGO26J8HP82hPDwZ3Nb540tTkIVE83fpd@jD8SINjQw0rGNCHyzcdnyHaXHGvoyRymMqzFSdVFc3CV3ugxgVE5heLFOBDDQi3mMVJ5hSwUZzBBrDTmWUQceF8rHmLgJG47Z2ceNQMenm6WCS4w7w1vWhIkQhuEyak58v/d7@xqWyMMD4ZFh@UQjqAPTpyODF5NGabnLsCbwItqEtyPGCNo2vMSMeOLLKjYAqbLi9Sq1MDx0xXeugywxmSlIaUHwV@nqbsuZypqscb1T6P186kOKTriw7sci1JZ@hJvJd8fcKbOeymul2O2KKjN/p1q0PLJDLLOEzo2RGU0/bqtxE96BBDdyyZybmdRxpah9dcXo9ZJAsQLmONU1t0RCPlbJ@gOUhiX4XK9XhQG//2Mj3llpazPvOSrlsFucAHMVhEBN/LyRM8ovex91upBcgHusAI2H/NDwN4TiRY8hAN03kddrYHEzefPnPOnHRhdcNzSE82cliyGYJmlGwGnC0Nr2wU3ZOyMpJd@1PALHzU6LZaQV/nYoWq0pv5VJdmT9Gc/8Wwu5BvuHWIiQeOxcvDDEwivRBc0/Nw5HeufHp8Mzge@dMabEL086DP83mE7R3CZoR3MtGXQ16jlRaIGs4t6skRTTxqiOQV5YPk0xyTaMCZ@CxxYQ4CgjsI4D7N@MP4YC002ONn24WRnmnfhEm9YAklZCfqCz44uUjwhb9XeCNtnd8BbbrWjcDySJ9mrqkWGQE/aAdh6y3XYFG/hyc9QT92DqFTBwvh8bXRXCutekCgea1yfX0oA/aHvjDQhxei2Iybl/Wr6964KyO7Myw9Lqw0e/cxqZP6uup77j8mk@Es7qxxYLunXVilkS5DjCrCgihhuhVLf9TopvGT2TESGkRV4bQfxWWij/xt6Stzw9L9llY1MCuHdWCjlVMcZ8JSN6B2KRHts8qM@mlM@UA4ACkIxuKQLp4m1nxrzzHOMOYNIWZiJvevobP/LSu5/IZOGyIsab1U3DOZh0W6PkUVpFVeDrEtrRYohW8eH1wFotmKOmEpr9atcZxM83dXWB/Q3GLSn4Uq7bVtyy5PYwstJhxqf00LnUaIoZ3ZngUaqy2M2JIEsZyhJEZgPEtLtxyVPpdtsFICJRnmWSFbS0xmpHPYGzRxZ/NMGzHizidPS29GAqKiQFMtzVRld4s2NvH3RatetINpWOMypS2yq2gDjWTWOUq4IYMHERXcRVThlyGK4ZqHJ/7ym6EpjoA4lm4TiXnka1iHuGbZa91EEN3hS4S4p0YQnmljjqDb6GHSwAiw2eZgArVkv6GF4UVV6QBbjMvC7BjuR@9Y62EFMpwJGTeGOA5DuB5hUt0kSFcJ@B8THAOXukKDTswCAiJrLmEKUXwYYoPwbawRkrJA5ZJeQnyGckm@JqiwVvCok0f0hBG4v0K8ZzaIRzHtO8FvuKGQyLGo6hJA@PDuR3vdPWbp2PjmmqSBI0dGaWbPi8MhBhU8ZKXOJSWVhaugeeWpX2igJltJkfcgtPPkkoknAAJLGphTDzqj2kti4A0DGIbJyMnm3MgNi/VDbej@I9m/NY61r4JQgBEQ8lo6QPmMroDmCRYJgQJZaYGmnocpQLWJnZnbSySqkbhIqI1Rst7BC7JVzzUImVmhXTpU0Q2qo7FlVZxrNdUWIpWcW025mGIUrRl0dBQ00RBurFShZ9mDxeyQg7blRm4AiwMlTZMxdmUPZ2FBCWxksp6RMeYq@jFEMRwxZJz1Jd5ihnSBCeFLQrxsKbBMjNQ3nGt/4AJSIlqdC/MFEWSvkRwSWWhyEd6v@wbz87FDVb@GHwqGGMzEGxFOiKOa3C8RNImfi9BZfD5ApGTQ@9uh0p81E48lVbm3@z5a5L14rcB7sb33TMMcWhtw98G/3SbH@VJgabT/qEU7@PoJ779kpoB/mEApXmFskggAtw/Hntw1/iTS67LhuM7Xphv2i3qcuNy1WrAdA7OlgKY06Ilj8kFSFp61gy0lGPhZG6ZW0rl7YYWgYiIos5qZ1I70MkWKmaX@6qwEhKm2hHE/gebIvYgiOfHoatDkvACwQeH3NmUFIL22wGoRKkRc8RR/SkzlkzanKWzLSuYRqMW6dCtjEHhoECxjbY/88aNErOhIjh32VR@TRIGUNUuHYTahaj9fJHuMXLb4aLksuUg27cVIPFtMDkG2ePEL2/jrymmRgRbacQzkDi5UMuCTygEohgnqoYdxZMwXrmUfuf1yse8f4ssfdWNY/MOLL4sG/c24ELMYCTHNuUJMVEBqNdHwRvVMeWIPsGz7pCEvitjD/Q3i/cG60f0N5vbHN7GrqJxUHlC3@HpOt@ObgdQwhCodkv1xbkfIa3lNXziyti@Ue3dB83xH2/CLf2zDf9/bcM7gArONPrDTWFP/j7n/e5h7zF/ZW8@v5@u/2bmveefYhOXMnLcq5TxVha1v1s4mu/mzycbywV@S4@RWMfd@BH/Hyb8kV9eT/AgP8OuF/vUpuZXcxGKrt8lprlwuw6O0UtmDVra@N21iqekm/LO1ottdnSa3MmWq/lNyaxUeCsUiQHI2qW6cTdbz@L9T@iOJH/bpihE@7mt1SDltZEPgs0BxkSe1fBBGTe5Yu0MNSUCr43EDKe780GiGAEbnmUlxPS@yChAQJ3/4FMj9WzpthsiPlD9mTBlNOOJCp30QXz2uBCvAdOHBH@qCdnsRvaKEEzrXBEoJEdDq4nl2FY@uLyQHhQHA5JsgMZNduUG9cKljTG@Gf7fy3zgmH8VLJ5YEI362KbviuuyK/5tUw@n4ctAvzslqn1Q7MF3jQP0QMixhvzscBmOW@DtBPxhRKhMYDgo6eM1eEy8l7HV/ZPe/l7px1aSG6j@EdY7N4Yayw6lynn0LK6t7RVrRZ1iV@hnPx1aX9S9g3HhhG8bJ6OiaTnd8ed2gCwmOR9Pa@IAyUeQwqfmYs1LkQJZr5K58dBygNP4hkBiUAHYwuu7n6GI3ENgwVgZz71/5PwJoeJksDK1Vh2Jo7P/RpZtbw2BIIS6Tdtuha5KCXusoGPojnzPWodf8td8JapiJByYjvHRQeUqqNxRcM7ZTExtliTAOcrjch5Xh7GHE@8OUDv8k1CqF4cZ0XY@DcerChIh3O1mKmoBaDocW0BXh7cFgHJXnqHFTgX7Ga1A@NpgkDg3Bw8FoRMDNcfxLGoglpeQFwRH9lE6jF9QRQTNSXbxGA0cV9K@viHbMtbanhZfnkrOuXLCuFyeP1/WXcqW84yBCcZrE2FxYxy/X7HtJ55IJSR1gxgGCNUMCBXlCrum08Ao0hTAcNH6gREvIlWBBIv1l9TdZ9uRGD49o7O4HHZ94xU0Dk/HA21Y3pAJYM9f5DLI7oygdI9XGdSfM8lqgwIpuGF4HK2vrywQQ7fi6aGvQjBUt5qDlkT@a5gi4y/FVz4xiY3ypesGnoCfeKwQ2pfPlRUl0hjea@dc9cmtZ9Yh0AJWxkQIW3I00v9ut7u1Xjqu7aRBTVrB4SGFJpqxrIZc/L9H3dg8zNTAZYRVevtnG6jITuRumU9@iRY5B/9ZG@5INsG4gDLO4B3SHbqpM1cTPghtWQ1Tb@520OQ6nVEM6azQuNwTlmq6acDRy9cpPJjGkK8S@kkiCscQGUAcHpiO3Rz1gPHcK3csrAAPC3epjoMge8k@kXGfzaSZj1tRLesoAY81kttjI4uz0uqB4pg6v@zFum6K146sUMDk8/mfW9jRFfCHrlNRlGfX4UrOcL5m4vU/utffFXEndRihcRtzxYHuq58@9lsg0BxDikZezDpn87/9KeaXbKIlOzx17ePWC@lzWmaOzzNSrfFetmwqbMFljqPY5Ow4m4x3O9Fkel0yFxqA1zVJyrdYOaNUt97Pdx9D1vsBevbTULJdfeF@gy9EQM4AOgRkGx9CiV8J37dg7EyKWOzvr4wXUixi69@H1/iuYcvQTC8Lx6Z/PF5/l0qmU55VwCH6Z4vt2D16/RSv/yMuStX9vNLgSvIx800kWZvsqPM2fE/RpB4eWw1UInLMTjGX04fb02O@8AWnJTfmAAnRLosA4mJTupi/xZSX0TUKZCy9nsXFUduKT63hfOmUqdTkK2iW2VdyG5U9uxyuN4c@l3cUKdFEuFqn1MVQqo1fTDNa7fditXx2/3i@nNn2FrZbnrIrUUsMQBxAKEYyLryp4HVWMdICrEFWNOVqPCAb@W0o5W/GxbOb8rVTp9vZeePY5ny4IP6mIgFvudVooblS@O6WlUUQF02FQxhe8tX1XPXbSUBdTsODLPm5vU2JaHMRa1n0wuSGnoC1weoRlyuXlhQV6h1Wuw3K5mM97mBHlFloL8f54aJYX1qh0O/LLLdcg0h9259yWVMwWcxzIEuYKq8X8yto3gxFsEWW8kH4hBBZSRq3lU3c8XQDZMCjrm5cWQE6G3bT8dHlx/aC7/acPG0eru26z8X3BSTs/hOS2PxraAIz8myyLRcBjR5Jrl4DAyMWmnxv6Pw5yy618EyTPwlorWFsJ1vMv1psrwYuNxsbGRrO9vN5obaz5ayvNRg6TvVOV7FW3D1KSw@SP3bYf1@19gtl6Mb/RbhcKq2utlY32RjH/4sVyY32llV9ebq8X/BcvVlvF9cZG4@tSWwRPAhis5ru4d8xy4Of3C3eJO7xdanv/Bw)

I use relative get instruction (`G`) to separate [Befunge-96](https://web.archive.org/web/20040221081031/http://www.mines.edu/students/b/bolmstea/mtfi/96.html) from [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge-93), like in [Befunge-96 egaugnaL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167745):

```
         v

                >"082",,,@_
        [>]R 10G|'53'S 
[@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_
```

First Befunge-97 and Ahead are separated using `]` (turn right in Befunge-97) and `R` (turn right in Ahead) respectively. Space after `R` is for Cubically.
Second `]` is used instead of `<` because of Re:direction. Ahead (252) shares `@` with Befunge-93.
The code `10G` results in zero (Befunge-93) or nonzero (Befunge-96) on top of the stack, then vertical if `|` separates the languages.
`10G` is used instead of `00G` because of Whirl. `'53'S` is Shove.
`>...|` is infinite loop in MiLambda, so `[>]R 10G|` is placed on line 5 instead of 4.

`101111` on line 5 fixes Whirl as described in [Intel 8080 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157799):

- ensure there are even number of `0`s before main Whirl code
- ensure there are no two consecutive `0`s
- add/remove enough `1`s until Whirl works again

Pulled Spoon (`M MMMMM...`) out of 1L_a because it was easier to fix Cubix this way.
LMBM (`;` below `O`) and DOBELA (`_` after `,`) as usual.
Trefunge-98: `@,-1,:*b5<>` → `@,,"76"<>`.

#### Ahead

Ahead broke after [this commit](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead/commit/4de9134509e56f1b7ccf4ee1e819de89f37673a1), which adds this code:

```java
if(cell.isWall()) {
    throw Exception("Head inside wall")
}
```

The code fails on `#` at (0,0). I see no easy way to fix this, so I use old version of Ahead at [commit 505f9cc](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead/commit/505f9cc46937013e5b90789c13300ae86b0ed214).
I cannot fix Ahead in the test driver because Gradle doesn't have enough privileges to run successfully. So Ahead should be tested locally.
Building Ahead:

```
git clone https://github.com/ajc2/ahead
cd ahead
git checkout 505f9cc46937013e5b90789c13300ae86b0ed214
gradlew installDist
```

Running Ahead:

```
ahead\build\install\ahead\bin\ahead.bat polyglot
```

#### Golf

Before:

```
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]*****<                      
#endcomment K`250                                                                                                         
#nocomment outtext("155")                                                                                                 
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8                     \@,,:1'<                                                                   
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                       \=#x=4; print( 1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2...
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                :~-<~-<$~-<<<~-! `=> $/#                                                          
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #                                                                                                    
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]+ pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*^e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*             <e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
```

After:

```
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print(#~$+/ .---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]******<                     
#endcomment K`250                                                                                                         
#nocomment outtext("155")                                                                                                 
#ce`  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @,,:1'<                                                                                              
#  |!o51@!00:8:8; ; ~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EV...
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~-<~ -<<<~-! `=> #                                                                           
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #                                                                                                    
# '>+ /' 25  >[};]+ pppppee^ee*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
```

I moved PingPong into Haystack/Reng/Reticular to get rid of `$` (in `<$~`), which allowed to move PATH's `$` (in `$/`) from `` #8M`| `` line up to Objeck line (now `$+/`).

Haystack/Reng/Reticular/PingPong code is also executed by Klein 000/010/111, so we need to jump over `@` with `!`: `@!00:8:8`. `!` borks retval, second `0` fixes that.
[`!` instruction](http://web.archive.org/web/20041015052658fw_/http://www.inz.info/pingpong/Ref.html#reference) takes 3 arguments in PingPong, so it should really be `@!0000:8:8`, but two zeros also work somehow.

First space before `|!o51` is for Pyret (`#|...|#` comment), second space is for ADJUST.

Haystack and Reng cannot traverse Paintfuck code, so I use whitespace on the last line to redirect Haystack/etc.

*Note:* Befunge-98 `<` (in `<e 5`) cannot be moved beyond either of `\)`, `∙226ｐ`, `|_|_` because it breaks Befunge-98; it cannot be moved beyond `X222999` because it breaks Trigger.

[Try Haystack/Reng/Reticular/PingPong online.](https://tio.run/##hZBha9swEIa/51e8iTNcEhTFSVzcONE6aMs2WJfBvjVdqjia7c6VhK10NXT965nkrikZjL2I40V399xxa15lu13CDRi0Kuq0UGbgTEs8aFUaXH4@O18t3n19P6fbqqRFvqZSbcTqTm22hahaIskUiEQn43VlePIDCMIpOjF0bTIlx6BKG/qS3ZuVFD8Hugb5fjg3hiO@YkshUzQKThqsmw5CMl7eKVk/011REwa31f9wJk@2BS8xGTe4crveQ/6kXt2gXP99lReQzmWqldstihrQLb/nIEnBq0pzkz0z91ULaxbOHOB2Oy84Rueo@/Z4XNz3/XAY2xDEIUK86S4JGXWvPHin3WvOzaoD0JaTBzy2VRictofDaTSNYsR4kh@/QPvjiW9PtZx7D/NJrMtcmqOAtbzo080jMBNVwjZpmo8aRymmT2TmHshsZk0bN3MGD3bCic2CsfPLM/LhoscY69n/f8o2@KwP6mMU2rarX/F1H9pJiG9C9GRveVC//A0)

#### Other stuff

`_` in `aat_` on line 1 fixes Trigger. `_` in `aat_` on line 2 fixes Delimit after removing `()` around `7aat`.

Removing `'` from `'#CO` on line 1 breaks Pyth and Delimit. Removing `'` from `'(22)S` on line 2 breaks SWI Prolog.

`[']` on line 2 is Japt killer, see [Ksh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118064) for details.

Answer (score 4):

## 302. HTML+TIScript (Sciter.TIS), 14194 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa














































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p><script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script> onload=function   (){d=document;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,2][ (":"+[].sort).length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-29]}</script>
<style>body,text{display:none}:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::tfgek:eps>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1, ute_[2]!!\0b=ad4ocod"r"n;z 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+1;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[[b,0,170]!!i_|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4@ZbnRyQLvA0UgSqgCg/iQaCbzSbvpW53s0Wyb18JRKMLQAGoJlCFRgEk0Gx2SJpdrTX2zno0skOWPb6SZjwrrydivBM7a3nHnomwv0445pN/QPuxseHYsP6B9pyTWYUCCIDdsh2xsbEggcrKx8mTJ0@ePCefDdPr/vznEfywJ25v2um5IzayvBFrDe0La6ix@1N2z7S9rJGWJIy1O@yM@5Yz8opShOmMeSNzOGI90@mMzY7FIuBrsNl72@6NrGGCeZbFGlbPvYTwNGOOdckOnabdAkhs5J5bjv3aGkJYhrEHVu9N/82INd1@33RaHhsMbWdEoVnGnpjw0h43z5nZ8EZDszmyXQeCcow9dXpmv9EyGUUfDC2eaJsBqOY5pZkPyTP2yB16FuTgNi3Pc9GzAJ7m0HYf7j7@ZCG@nmKfmIDUoGdNFrLXdfbMtoatxRQG@/z04GDRN80@U12HHdxESc@w3fHIPRwtws@y3Y7lmMzQCpqxGJgDYo6sXj6VT80FQdiBPYTaNEWtFWc144z7DWsIxBdVeGmPuhokOHU5wZnr9KbMmgAwwLEN0awRs7G2WDaVwpjwf2I1Xac1Aw9eFsABuFZ/MJoylTmu4AEIcofMG5hNS21ZPbtvj6wW69mAndsW2HgMKpydW9NLdwgVr3JWJES8gdW02zYmESXwJGS2B1Zj3GHueDQYA3oea9me2ehBtMaUtay2Oe6NEqwBYUA88r/sWo5AyXY6WI5nMx@E4EAT4Nhv6kAbu9djgM45ooNZe2wHAy7RH6M2LMLSaiGo/Rm5AJLZ8/zSz2c8lw2mezJ0O0OzD4zasogGnx8@YV7THcIbfDEubwXrwDTNEdvZYdH9xw@irBKQURs2pICkZXbFGIv4gezC7I0tj/XNKeTtjKBxMZfqz08hQXQW3YgWWTSdZkaKZTIsA40tz4xsikGTKIADWq2R1uGbY0aeZXTg@2w0gfm0h2bH7lkcSsfttRHQNnKskWUG/KYy0QQPbVIe2yydZ7lttp1l2/BbYAUDMkGIGaYXsvDNwRcgFAADHb7pDM8pYAtkJygC22Nts2/3phz6YIDgmyyrs22ACGjqANnIA4SCgRDmP2F4oy4QtmteAEi1Z5@juLACiYG1lYRHcmsrSSILZSPP0utavR7mCoQCEmXzbBtyzUGhM5Az0NHIG37hO10qPuG1nYIv4LgNJc4DeVNAqRSSahu@8A5iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDr4G@BOI1SIl4OwHNRVLiCt0SLagnSFtDoSEwWKjjSAZAyqLp1hUHkZqN40Vm82zQBPQGA7x0Cm5HWWz7D8NgNyFVIMSK8DMlj3OsgyHZDQERhUqQ51qgMiOjCLDkD1dJZJIbrqaQyHtGlICyTQM5AmA26oFz2HX0gHFa9DljrkaRiFGWsBbkYWCplNE88ZOai8bQgDYhmAqwHcYgC2Rh7CMW0eCJdHltz2CWH2Bl0TaQE1gIwMrAYEyQJOBBvig9vYTnOWotgNa2Q3pWsJWhXvAcMSx5ceKAFAmjCTYQcKDDjjnlggARUQSPPCauxZPeAikCFNE9zIttDaUXL4cOyRhnIWuinLvcCOlJr/XDYeiYjGEHtRkFctazhkGBc6Wy9BwsQbNzzr1Rj72hlebZBOFgjWtmn3AgSo6Zgj6gfgGfUgv@k82u2h26f21Udh0XPdwQqxC6LpEgF96l5aM9RnksscDHogz8HfAkKMzR4gc2mSPkDqQjhXjhAkwnTNrg0AKSuQq/bQahLtRdEhdRok8DyKRWZU7qQRyv1Qt5BmAxeEqodpnHGvV4TuzmqydCXZsi6S6MO7jvkuA3HwOxPoDwWIhgl9OXWmiEUA6Y6hUTd16tes5/bni8bFy2FQ9K6NXUDv0pxC7bVBslgTsw8aB8Nu3YGOuw8cw2sQa8LjHc8ha7lOdBRAuRxC9wqFDkoCIHtEk5Hdt0AfcyEJ1niGkEbhRpg1psDKRK2MRuoYx2SBUJq0SCjukQl58MYCHVtr3ESqYd62QxwEHYJHvVUF4HKlU0MHNLmhZbZ4NNQuEKOQfgS9nQVEF6pAkwChhmI5Hmg7nsZsVAuB4TtuG3iMumhQNSDpLJ8mlR1LHnhNtKYmEaWRb/rnPWaz5mDAwB/0E0DrIJWHPtZ9abPXENjreqzXHA@HUzYZQAXYfYg1arrtNjDta2vQBRCs32LNaRNaJZQSmUZquSSBmoOFIgdvmxbEcSwo9t6Tr7GOBdSGHrkNmBKnzwowGFARiBSmw3trxwRKYRGagymRBcAEKdquq6F/y7U84hHQZoIWj5l5VodaBDSv9kwG9VH7AOYEjcABlgWBI1oVwscMpaWFwaxE5X9iOdBimsCM0Nah@lAf3WVt0P1DnTUqd2azaQ1Ggj1ckmK2E1Jojg5QoSFfVQDTvK60eQ90sTkMJIgq@ZwT6sHNcxKuqOiTnmWiiBUGBvTpjhWosIwLlN70RvYQ42Ihd/kFxpnD4IW8AocBtQTU7kg2jEcoQVAo2s0uisARChnSMqCRDcc3iw9@4eyHfaa2g7wRGx2kjaQlAy/EYzUMFb69m4C0QQ9hVeY8MOqcxy2gTa@/BLIbINlrhX21pKmBLLwNaN913CVQgZgBXIwyH0J1Qcx4glLD7AXMSM3Fm6sjlNMz2xf7L@g6BwN3CC2DC50pSjJeZSHucrmdEgu6CAXs5vkeFXqKKPbzoxG3uQY9sIOoiWFLBX3SBEkBQoxbACDzXJ5jCGFq9QRL4HdJEp8zE3ShjmOhSmoOpxwIFA96ZchoyuzhEMTgBfYNvOvx@xCN@BS6ArPVQsmK5KB2v5i5hhy9N27Yk0Uzo4me2ktPujCHrI0WxhB0DWhEsWjbiyol8qeUoSA56Q5GSUrKf2WISJE0qPJYG4wW6AgOQNCcTJ1mTJ5rYnKCyeNROy8r4MCEXDVjXzEHo0XsXoIfMk3/HNo1vZVYB3ptVYVfFf0IEwxIahhgDkG9gEYIWnah0GqY7A1IjyFTJ3uUGtVCeupaJsjLclpBXoIQiEu4vBrPwhs2yaGGejUsAUanklMnMUfA96QEJZTBI5kU/Sd6kJLHw0id4Z5jh4YHWIxrIAq7ClR06ABihIwNOofdtEd1oaXcuePrKxvlMjAbKFEgNltKWLn3x1E0kNQQWSMlRGSijdyTEbaNmALlxcjXHBvQloBTyxV2NeoOocXR@7UEkYCskoOc7BNW1PNj@3zcWqxoBz0xkoytDnQluzmSSxJ0/rw1lNdRNTpHVVD@o0hVZF5MT6BvMC/5YoXKItrQ8lDrLQtUQjUcQwwEry4lEU8q/GYMvTdt9oRKwF3Q2Lk0agD658JSDwRRQugEfqO90VI5EGwOHA57snv6aVm0RR6YbNhOcc6j5zbNHnlvYnTZT/vw8P7x7vHX6ktg9OxGcdEjaWfyOexqxxO144yTGc0oboZhzAA/qK@HjQnn48iSCGaqOwmpStMmdC4Tn5xHx58tkgQ0ISQH5QBu/C6oNDwOKF1Sw/S6C50w68TjkGWQxI/L1EPmwwwciDqGmz4@T8avX2PlLSI1EP6IWW9scgC@Z/LQ8dNpGLiggPlBjTbvESktaKG2g@OfM1c4po/PJ6g1LyJDqnSIZT45Otg/LhPYrumdW72eSlGS3gh0KXPY0oDne@OWJS2LA@IPXE0W12aIoz5NuC4lcLM5R@BZ3bIV8AEAmjiay9Re3y@a1wXc9xbLRr5qM@AAeicIi3plWB9qfiiiITywi2uipbusF6WAWWcVeC3tsYLQ@W6rmc1a25lCuNtqzvJshYH2SSm2XV9vHELQuaeijzbTIoVaLdA/eXgDcY@USDAFVB8zr8c0ysvrSWi9qDaLesk9sNDcnqU9I4knM1lJJqP@wKfW9MjmDMXfn9ijWErhT12BuJD77u6h8cCPLAbqaACDjAY0wbFnGrZxoqHpAY84bs/tuGwL0nDt0M8Q1KaVxdztuM6NGjLRE4sawZkLkL84XmMOoK@xX5PhSKnC5iqf9TAd7xKktJ5LI5GIQgQqSfG1l@aFCeSalfvk8Ov70Ino2VQqcKfoAyQIpSFyoasZ8iUPpkJGmsBnaQGDWYwbrd0PUEPTCFhoIeiChLuz4KWeJDG15NL4S1H6inuD4i/d6QJrgQ9nLXCESHb4@MnDw8f7j3a/OBsZ2ezceyZVyAHhIL8G6EJal9MNW@sWb5pYLAQXgbYxxOYFUmAMBoo/HD72hiC4NYyicQRWcA2f/4l9xe06UU9ZLMwlhqovnSZnoUfY@HhUkRAM7VYPjZEhnzbD/hz5pzsaDbxiMgmtvDtuaGC0Jl823Z7ZSVI66Bh6vaSOpsvhEY5reMtSADLe1OIp@JgWqA5TGjg0e30XjBeaikPRwGIcPA1W9exOF2xhnK@zhooWcDCVJtkCCwFs5WRQNhLA9Aa0FU@/nmTO2h/pRp7ztZ4yMknZjzbX/CHuRtsC0ykGvRWQQll4ZWd3zu6wKUhphLQIJMK0LTFlg31Bj4EiSYOlaOf7xCFpgcOkKCuIRq/GOIgLUiqZTWW29Vw2CWYZmGmgs6o41Kb2zVGzq45cFeCpbpvGDUJc2PaaptPWtoTDRxb0vo@hqOnq87MzpwYK@tkdwg0nwqrTWlWvKSV2M8mWiK@UgHvnioe863sA75ITWJOey9oWn7YNtT80VpFfbDfq0Rg36gM4uOgNIHMam22idPNwXG0EvUrAMSjdgCgo3NilFcVhZ9Pjg3uQSEzW@enBxgkg0CB2MIDrBJOUQDxKRWYttDioDxxl7M5G59BYhhqCDAknNNqh53VosL0D7RMS84Ls8oLwnMhnvkjnYM47CK1hsbzasEd8bNwdD3ESzG6FywbR0waPA9CocCF5SLNlDavJRyd5YioFGE8mmNZgQIMJDloJNSGLimDymTa0oTwc4AV2TKk44QDwVXZvD1p/0@LjLGofjQ@mDvZZdDRM7qpfT5rqa@CCNToJFn43PPFLlX7qE4BG8IKZXxpdECOH1Ku7fYr0jMYpMPC@ryZKg@moCyVWm0w2y@7AchZtJW5JxZQSzU9GoyAobSd2Fd3Y2IgWo5VoAlx3wbWDrrvoioPrLrlUcmE8DV2UIkEuDK1SCvSrRa@rPuSJUkMemGCP@9oexMxqsZiuJcyqLp4GPhWoCqA8xFbxAXCiSrmMTkWRK5c4xQF6b6jse8g7J82hPRAk@Ap0pPxd0CBNRACzGLXgoVVCm249RfrlIRhbFqpmsWH0rJo6q51dnbXiZ9fRBKZWSmYZ7Cpo9KNYX@sM3fEAFJ5qpqiCTFCq6WKt1ChHU9GtWCyv9iAjU1E@zitxk9M6FrWAp2JnZ1EgqaBOtdkdErxJwlCUgFCAB1jrLdD7YlHtKg/5N5SaEo9CWiWaAHFWjkaBLk0kgkeFRkuaM9GBPQFSQsOEriE8Fk@KEs3lYHP9ujXoTofhCMFoFWinOPI8m8SGxkDSL9yzv@bpw4rQnIXs64s8HiiFOOiFesZgyqWixDE9S84tqPD7qwu13XdHZvJzDYwNLdTNRDeiSVWFHoRCOCQq9iPbwyZsOpY79sIjdEsHDjF38D3tjkFY@qtNEsBV9kCyml2XRTfvAXQWTI@gSoAzPSqfL/IBtJoafFGIYm@OkwzQK9MyDBvkIi7R4KMZOiHBRY8/pp3NDV5pQW4lSsNSmJHdcdyhpQJJIIVEiyZoiY1UYWIlxiGNGN0Yzxehe5AlGay2BRLxoOeaRFsurkPzKIN@KD3YtZDk2GpJPZAfbRCPGq@LodVKbkk0qekOu9BDQGlQEhtBbfVFQNL1Bi1tNIGkUgy0vrlAbhWBsnbJWoZh5JrZdtEPQ64AYnehktCac8A09INUHQIVUcn7fDjFt20fHz3Y52MOSdD6aNQCx5/qfbc1Bn1M2BvHltNJsH3gJ9tx@zaQwU//@rx37Lojbh3Dy6oRDW5s2v1xz6SxksXhjLXpmm7D7dEQyrqks/jjoWf2TD5444fufv4IdOSnpydlrRiKlDQv@mvzxvG75dlyeh6G5@poetKfVvE4Y8qbWRn7LX8RF4oZEZDDgLFYwgV15Ptvo7/fpHDuQfjn0b@Py7dAxxTWN70GniJigSLiki5cCSM8r/TUNfqvtF2CeDrF4wrXDNsr3SD/i1G7PeedJu9zFUVTb@adIW@@tGvOtgqjlOWRcJ3XXJwwoBzFCZZ7LcYTwiuYmu9aPX/m7RgUE5xdgr69h@oT6PSowfI1VxYooAOcRCAJjVNTrNk1h94Ncx/a1EDlsaXIBrUT6MOSqLlIm0kmhoZL1FLA3OZTeh6Xni6YxDTqsFPhE71ocgy5tZPkg9abdQCxUyn5q3BWRcOcotEgGkEl3CAFFZOmu28UNVi84NFYtERJSpKXBG17YqTUs8n2fi3pERHaTD47m3ycMr4ApR3XSm3eSXasEma3klr0zsdvm10QGyw@mScZ1MPYabu9lsoni6D@GTczsCLEFH2wWosEPvjYQ3@hlo2LP8SCOhCXoTVeN@AuVF3lZoTQqrAAELSGK/bmPHHxhlWhB7vQvEHPHtXYtTZy610s/Gg8dBbXj3GVcjg0p54kVniU2e7xJ59XUzUOQeqbOAGU57U18Zcfgh4Meg@u8gQXrlMZ2SPq2GlC3sby6hogNaG5AkAfYPAMSizISJQIUX9jvZmVpW2BwRazEHNv2k8wS7nW2j1zNLIczlt8Fm41ufl0icimTNnfFWPvRZaiCQpQNG0MAxRL7OT0wf7xsQYc6sWi@ziRUYRmZza7oG@sKrRPyXDhi@zjVpR9jGkUtF4laFJgTNRFemDeEjA3mBOQO4qCjjWMgaeCcxBN8KZpH0rIFS5BIFxt1BwRjQJgMbCm73JgxaX4P3W45STwLLIoixMlgdyxO0Wgra1oY8d@pXnQb5AaClGi3PakpaXlzRiJr01dIf4Z2n2cQwWTibRAKEO1yjZAulFsmZXfsufVlFqoxTdZrVbiM@OQEHV6Wqoqlj2agp58GokEpMD5UFhl7YXFr34ONOKJqTh@OvCsJPgWkB2OG9ObrVTeNGQlQFZ9DR48UF5EcsniTI6ivySIRAitIJpfCTS/zihUrKdkZC8sqobi@AgE5cHpuxgvJdsoM11RfMw4oGfmEE3nInviep7d6NGqz3bP5iuogs66KAgjIPmUCWdXwoZBdMP2DO0MK2O21JcvoBWUoHDqaMCSwpKRR0xhV0hMIqWBVGRv3qCHzDYNRmwg40pbTt9r36YF@fjQBWQfipXDYZ2DhIZY1oGi40ySfeNtft4UQ7hhkLxY0HnVCzmcjuuctnPu0uxL4KqnND2LemaQun/eu5mybXtd@pmLGuDA4xqrsPP6jTb9LIlAkxBieps8aHhbaNhQnWbymB400r0k5/klHXPZNqz22OnQXCC6mfrqlphqIU@R242GvSoqEAFXafnPJdFAVmLLM7SMpvutBwd4oFsE@cltolnRF1cDsTm6Qyc1glTi@V@/0QL636ydLvRXOA4YOOqgKWBNqe2VlSWS4gv9LK9YPlw97tkmEYZct4FsmkMoktkLHMtB05S4qoK@0ccBflHjwJv4A7roGjbjmPP5Of@5PJNlU1wOyO3mqrgLq6N4VjQZA@Zii4jAdS7bokQkZHklWBM@IRIy3FHg3o6Uv4SJETPzeu@OR2P@C@rwrZVoD/C7rm2KmKms2dAtMEjNhm2tqfKheT5uuergvBOoxbklcWelpxlZFbQSMTlbR@fy4vMCDu0OdPf@c1W0Wf@avKTHbVzhOWNvoDbItm/xN2oI/TU5DHv8d1UUW@zwCRyrqWb36Oc9OVFAB0YRaxOSuPJTDRHNXiBzz2xMURXqfjiXBfP8IHHKzXg8lV4x0TsYrE6P9imlLxSWp55oTU6PZSMPSb66VOVjc1Rgsd70llqF7srumz3VaIWcK4X5smUCN6IGM4yUxrrA@ZWLpTU3oz52SM1xzxzOXGtYfIaHPzmxapxbdBuiLTfdnu1hg@6tkpr@WrVZXri@l35C6xHsZZRsgSGK/bgauJZLAbc5wjWcK9jqPWQaXzuJK1RDfKK5q4jVdC/xu1KD6IIxzH@Xd2qvl2L1HvJJ7TV7JnTlK3uEuVFHHNW8hVcvbc@in@WEPV@K6KjZW@o/3wr88cTw@OBtnO3ZPddjJ/S7jkCdIVCB/y7n6TAtbdNRaZQ97F4jhvxFB7MKNXsdt5fLd5Im/Kys9fGwjaJfPN9XyAVCStdvEVK@BuQ6uniuFO3nyeH5bRVE@6aGuOA05FzTyy6TVGJSZ3XpwDbAGcHlJTtI5SmlluRjiCsyxrmcS3PqP3@B3mMVaf3eYzAljRoUPExQyINjNORa9i@SW2Z9bq33E0o3wG7fVohQ5Z73LOiv6PdGlTIjpX9gCj2Ven8R1e6NrbG11NY4ary0cPvtGjvj/ZFKiWJsiikAnHXAvSJBrNfCOHwvrLGrxre1wsQEq926XZuZF2oDUMAHaD0/AccTdNxM0XHGg7lanTPQnOP1JOsO/Cbttuaww5APlUP5W5SlORXds@i71mjiRh6u2CpnUqmU0GFCUzlzL@uMqXSQ9qXNf@cyJp9ZzrO4OH03DDmX50FkCa8JXCmCjFW2PUUuFJKO7VijKf6@pzRtuG7vQ2oKhGrLRm0MlEta@7quxm6oO2JXB5uNXng45tForxq34L2NMC@BPmg3r6v08FzTe9WmirOpfZzpmn9dP4ITmrm6LRfcBo3DQnw1bG@1LikGRHQtr22vbXVcQ3UbVs/kj0kusw5eQUuvhTcvNMQsMM4a87ni2Rx/ZEEoDaZALLsFhkrX6lv0ukbRN1svx57/WBlp4uJ3VfDEsprJyb7VXBVhYINccPB3bnI6pCyNXAdMrBEuvENTpYdLO4XvKgnsTycuJfJh3@xY/GyHdZJyNmaBy3S4ZTdzLh@9KPKlOU1INhthXs0S0KjOrannP5cCfDRtQr2O@7ePuC00/iYOg75Ha1@1pvRmF@t03a7Ttbp8IXfwtqpxAD@O@Fkc61AHrDvdJiPRFF5zHqZnz@313oeeKBq5oHTd9lKc9nE3Km6l@iC4U7MBAeJx6/idOeKyAx0rW03XGkO/5Lkjd2Cp9LYqag/HevjvKhnqz37/ooNIa019oIj//EXh32pbdkx3NBjQoz7ojT36oaQqbSK@TW9q8zUvSHbmDjvaa7ff0ISnJhbE0KT7chHTsEfNLm7e5pxtddxGs2vfhnTDMkeOfZ70R33463vZrkgZm6kP0Fvr2UDe4VRDfimHw0/wcbiq0sUAEu/WAscafWXZIB3tk1YH5nnT4wOi6GJFHBMOtUa@m7pI29CLr8b2aAY0tEgqGOHlMxPoWIW7WJaxUrOiTQszMSyWa6zkUlLSUSFXrRQoPPrK8aW5BXShJpZO859VCIVLSRiFFrx8CLnFoiIaILRDQ7fgP8dfc6uhlnZyTnfc8W4KTD5i3wIVDX@WisDdDh7BhNtiXeb13EtaqkYnD8z21obGs6E3Mx3xWFUBRi@J@xHhWQdtbGytnXDJrp1xoXh6TzVdGx51eECljleOrvXsgcd/mdpeOU8nlk@Blb44mcipNl1uZosqa1ltPj@CrtuUx75LM7ignahNnO3H4XUU81wl4yLNcTsg7tUem0X2465SaJauTFrOGEFvqn7x2OqYuLz7oT3C9aFL@IWYedmKplthf3VsevZXx1CyVWyIhyvwOcpheBc@vi2B98js2M1P5yoiQFIQWCwu5Y@5hoFeN@vismt7uLoqcKwZskKW40yMXFcHi2JJzMVB/eBciVmr5zsWl8ZeNvDuDqa4sWtKrnVj7vaIxl/Fc5VRuWrd2VokLsf9wdgTj@U40Pqt8Ph0/5z8vUsbgKuvQOiyrtkbLR/DDg3Ggn4musuZc5We/nW753bY1/MpBuocqGeoti9hnPvQcT/BRUNDZwknUt7vOSeKQyAql33eK6hbK81U27FH68d5RiNcQOQ/sTC8T8FNEcmH@Kvd@1AI6ulyijy83QqY7SK@pecHzjtxx8Omhc7gaJCwwSBytfb8Bc@i13Csy7D9tnZeBzpK1xmP1OHYWdsr5Nb2CkU2yedCbMBiX91/9FQJcwMtEL9NP7XALBx7venMtXI1wQKT2Q6oaKvl6Hxs38p4wE8yOqbVybek2cXjlpokrh@4yyyhJ9OhNXpvUwqE/7j/wGrinOKteT92H7mOC73RAARl/9ji2/PnVoEsT4jJHuIGdKBP69ZsTgjsik6IaxvmwGpA/fZmrvfpizjgB@bIXNEV0aghWYaB61ZesXsNa/iShgND7lXG7jxCn1oTsjpWMwxvg@qo2eTKMo7UzbWRubkcb@C6Dv8laZuCh/5ovVSBroB@3n8WXcO1/3MjBkstt/miHl3wJSRWi58fsaqsQ6vh9vjvmgVLjs0XDJhD2/KSD/E4AvLLZZgK2pe3VoZsr5UhM6MJNNkL06MZ/OVGyAykPvmA9UFdc9h0cY5MONYs3QmdIXCLmA62E/BVBQ0g/AQkltkci9MMb0Or12/06WelKRGqzWOrgRuRGnTwxsic3KxMPmYkTh0ILfcK9ur74gobdY7FnoCdotzebc1ZWPNUtQf0Q5J65UQ6reRRHdtqvjZxPM0les1GrefCoczJx@RcMYodakY0vpw0aVP60pY0v64NFJqepY66QwuU39G6gW//RJQlMyXjvoXTz/PzMytVV9frUmHd5TPtgXAdWqo4jQ9kSXAyH9cP1d2VmieCh/@j@19JQidcz2X8U0JAdN0@tw/Ij4eOeLwPBz5xvVHbnhwB3rgjYZU4wWJlIQk8eMtA19aqQkDtOeMeH5fohBZl9Vtkjql0Iqyq9khcjyzVci5UOrNtcrNELt9nltzF40VHVksVRxbgHIT60N9yFkQTzyVTq2HZiCtB9SQn7CSXEWtDlxH30pcMoG@5I3Xg0TM58J4cPjw61Qaevtzq7@JOjRt63NwZCEY@FRqsemkOQzOhfK1ay/ZGyfsnurr38FDDCCvozec6VHjgnN3cY@WIqDjM00yaK60gDLVGyxXET08fPYzPdoWy2F536PYtJRy8d3KSwF0vXzlZGhxOfQCto@1OViY/3Nd1ZQn7PnVo3nCV9FyS0ypIpxZYo8CMn/IjVG5VrpruwGqdTgfW59B5ogT33jP73MpCPjYv7A62QlZYSShqqKyg5TJKaNk2GNvWMHiuqs9ze4DSskmPJH@sXKiCmkM6OUwv1x7WrQVY1GJYSqxR@LBEeuomt45sFVpGp4uupOn9fRHTdX0VnU/MNtQry66srPkIy2aOe@7Fe0wyW8J4UQMvdQRcpdq3LjLfVvsgupP4gwP3whOcjZULZNYBCLxzSxv8peVMTUelWa516kURUuNyt7VRvm69x1RVsPbnAo9YXjr7F6y3Z7EmOZVbMj4dhpLs7d0/vC3BsaDl@lifPH7KnpgenheyPmIYY@s9MJ5pRi9VHLfCw@pWTrS2hgDKWAuvM1jenovsxBy2XGc6uX16jra9YtdOx/8GsPCNIlk9e2Iv66uafFzryfIFSLflzXd4uNM5PTh8jowA9O7b/0LXUyk6JQifeoq/3lIzfgNnMXSZUzx6Lhx0ehiIhibqLRp4UAS@Eed47ISPVPUSYnM/3z/HdzR5mn/ubSxmxuOKMn@0enj/Ft@5ZOLh@rTpCOK@ecM2xN4iCAi2W4kdTXg@D6gzFu4DlHwQVbZ5Jfb/FIv6Ne6BkosyE/uzgrMK@Xl75c0YnhQGqDL1XMfLJdimv3mI0YHR7A0jtQbkqJ5NwZuWDO/mLIldVawI2T45fLJ/crp7@vSkmqpdy4rYO8hRM03IzN9V@nG6JUOJBDFA2@CHb9Luwx5kR4dZozrk@cViULCFkpXnSjYrk3wX02xemWYySZvokuo14KfKPDcKBdmHXhy2X2KiutgDWeR7z3pEUXmTg5YpT6iJIksty3hgeh4US4QvHqdPoSydxlCesTgvEZi047otkaNnsds/fo4Hu4cPnx7vMx/BGStc2q1Rt1zI8uM0UaSoFtRT26b5@DKLiiRRqKtyOXoQBcJEtSgr0tZFOsoSuBei@dTBTY8i9RaLbRJ8oGA0qJTkf/1G8jqq4dIyBeJGfaSiTFAeI7BT3I70Zz9p8aOe/UMI/Dsjhn1S5WmztyS2Gq7YaIgUpeY2WH1zBB2tTHsKgzOdZ7dxSHTSN3DlJWp4i2fLKHTcA78GRBz942dEDOIfD4sjEXiMD5hRFzZuKOQ4tPFUnXlWxmlNOoFJY7t4LQbwPLA@IgGoj50RP7lC7HOPAB9pgZhIsE1Clh9OLociRnc2gJUbVsd2mOeAemeNiuwl8Bla@0W@q1VVK9EbSXzQ/D4UtTvq90IRbxzD4yXPRsl3v/adZKfEwD1J3Ye3XxFvbXD/Knc/T2Jd3zyqZ5Z/GAk8lkpgzTMPaI70Dt0A4vDdwzNi4YlCvvxjdh@q5oIojdF5DvxXdZg8gxOrfg4VBSwGtSR2DfP8rGEthudiFZNJZCOcOdFopaQ14csWFs7HymVzGT0JSKoXPkA60LaDW7I4QEUpAuNLF/ag/KIB7LWzw2TUFqxyrsRrM7lpPk/LLwJENyGudNlF5KoM0kCSWQoIq4hk0EnEdQWTojyK6lEURS0Xeg8Kx14G3x1BCJnFgFicRhaekDrBq2BGw6l/zlsDr1cJHXa@KQCpOnRB5FJkSWx0feyOgGXmtvjyja64bIf3VDjJ7fGrjuh4NeRB7WZrmu3P8k9VF@1Lw3bPQaVTi51euG7lZwjiBEEU5WUsW33OzkZnTi3JeZMBm/5QsGyYmR1w/7NkZwXP8nLv3jwkLLZ4xBcSi907cVxUiw6gMCxmJI10Us8psyJlMkuLJEoksoHi4NEFbyA7EE0gJpqW/dIdeLt7@4dfOXpycuMgLIoZXYwGkryyEz9TtUS1Fjii4WLNV8n9g@TJo/sHfkXMkM6FJDDoJKIk@rqSzKwdBDlbV7tYtGUYLpZuNcbP@Oa7RXzTxjrUKNENPPTUB@RLa9vUA1qhvpi5kV9GrWx2HUozeMkQ6D2@vegGqjHl6rpa26mcOZHoTU5Y0hCeR7QtbATgOvO2NpPI7DcLhwULriQ7xctUvHBbTC9vi/JmGs9jwQ2OI/d8dhKN8AgFhMrrZwMiUtKSftSVre@I69Kz85IMfmUaP7klfF5FCOFcah3FQ6BO/dvXUIrMTnsTB511webo2Q3JPyeEH3jmn8sUnHXGz/iIKZI4a5tnHBP3sU2KE42mq2MKSjuClWDrzk7z4SkSNGjU156MwfZ54g742as0LfHA8l3HLojfB2M@v2mxr4z7EK9Nj2OLhohAcquQGCgZDVDl@hNICXF02iSOh9NBflU8QE0UXOu3srGJonWtScvugGyPKQmQaB/reo0Fx6thoek4NScqU53NamFtU/wEN42Fyf5BZ@xNZgiYVVOznZY1iUUvo0qxBvmjf/Ty2UVUkZfxEp31Jw6/ay0e@hegv62vlyTmSLRO/0S9ZdKiULgpJcBvETA/rca/@KFQ0LqeRPf3lFEXPxkNH4IT1IhYu28OWGzs8BN9NEavsbOYk6AjUNQKPxTMYfE4mUjwoACNUco2uXj/HTOdKYsly8AE6Os5LXy8tgesqmtaDdyUicI28UKWPdC48HQMRQJbFZIUCWwZWQgMB8CINxKNMzikwXAJDy0Z0rlIS4LpfgoaZHWRJlRqVrnDQvfqzGuOcqFQFBU6LxULDLjvpjjUkgD2hpzzdXmgrth9DzQDg1aTIjNBflPiRSjfCEfkU7FtH9CJhA7y83fzM4A1O2av2R3iN7bvQFvBA0iKT08P6nklKbNg@39naLdwpIef4RoYbeLUfWimybmo0RK30T7BZHiuU52fL4DHDh1Qg5EXRGokTIbFWyZnvKnra7leJBS1ADEz2AGIPRJ1HxweYObPuS0JWy7sf/5zvMdSjm3ezaXrvYt4NJsqwY9eyrIs@3jzTFU3q0Y2Vb63WTPN0ZnMzGRm68GF1W03DjvJM1lmaZZJJreM3KvzgZ7bel7VXk1qcjVfTpzXnpyzJ0@@eFt/q8iTi6l8FmPbEbZ39EbWoQCR4jYrMPwu/dAFc0s/a6x0OQpwz87wfkp5W04mq9Ea/FPQC/jwSNWKVtHu1t6@VarbUKbJ9CyC176xo3vzwGKGoZzYtp1kZwOv1YKv22U1fnFphH/i8ZjKhIda5X6sP2mT32TX6nTG@@aU@9uRMT4ORiLto68/e/YMHc/ow14fi/QcOvPzKNbNbIQZKePPfrpxnbh6Ut/5s2/2k9YGPo7w8Z3rR@g@0bMfb2x8fP9@JpMAKnH3k68/@dru7m7mQSL7pJq9m1FTGzt/@icbG4axYyQ3ap6n16LV8/MvZCOVkbU/@3G0/uTJVz0PqwU/aaaDE3/z8NVRpzpnr@Fz3mb4T@7XrZDbRHej/ZoZkdcRYOvIlP7qEcZbYZm0pPBng@mVu9v/7XtHryKjSMVIPhvCcxR5FcnlI9wJDnhL@28XkUpkB6PlriPTZLlcBuf2f/v3kL7yFYCDIdMd@KlkfVi5aaSilinJm0glBw7dMCDf/@sb37hl2Oceq8JHzmwb8t0afLbosyPhoUtqKplciK7n7@h3GHNG3ZHl4sPmDwcezCw5YHUfV@PxeE1T4aPVKVFS140zGrAJsxaNt0QC7xLjPizkN@MT4QNhzyLEU8BUxFfcLTyI1bjHs8V4z5Z8Ss/@sT/HUiS3cc96UKmAKDQqxlYlTp@Ns2KRkz/JtvOy697DEa3omRxlL9hDQeyKnMobciKRuFfHW4HZBGmqTiIzAjJOIxaZo2yEzd5Y2CvC/GRsFudD4@3j58//tz///p9/j/6@T9//hOdTOS27ndziyF9U@IdVKnJlKF@d0cs9lirmi/lknV2fxbaqldox01OfvIlm09ETLCNFYmeKP8IZCT6VCv74aOBbJcJ9Ktw18xMhleCFYsySLI/HhGTyiRqBLlgs1lGrFzWOG8cv/Jngh1XvQTXJxnZBrlWMrHEEVafLVHEF1t30mBsRJboLnw34o3/43MXBY@GDvxvkyUMo6pLPRoDK7Z85XKVItZqsWTVQZFnFB3Jvo7iRL@aKBlTKasClVaAjF2Fpom1rec0A8fG2usGOOa/XWNz/nMVv/TzVtLpwksPFr6q6k4gU@Uf4VCQWuYJP7e1W9S2wrsi6KtppfEetVeICI3ho9Xu1uHp9XdWex0sl8b9TCZwl@nAXFKR2rao7zwFW9SZUDpR@tfrzHQAb36nulN09@mp1JLFae16p7synFcnv3YujjL0HACqbNRbNuNGce48p8fimqm5UV5YBANdiDKwCqMDrnevKdXXn@npnB/536PdaPMH3eufGPz1mnxVxZuHUbM6qycpZ8kywTQ3etWQFfbTkGTgq8IR40A1JERUalBTZYluRAdO30@BiVlHfMtLJ7OTj3D6oRtWaihZMWa3quWxN5ZLqhcaKKj/UWs/nFA1FUd1t13EfmsZeSJEX7778X/B79u7L38d@H5plQYokt9A8KHArAX4eOezRo0f4feQ48A/fR/zjoA96PEI/h/84PIYfJ/DmPtQeSCrkc3I9rk8NFtmRc9soFn7pxicajf6TF0ZhO8otaNyv9cIDz19a9vknv7TqI0XeFLCdNz3GyyRFqN1DXUD7qaDzCn8ar/Dv4Wv8ezXCv9Mm/h2/wj92@hr/jkf496iBf088/Dt9hX@7Dfw77ePf/Vf492iEf087@CdFyqBsb95N9VLNlH6un4PDZqkhS3VTXb2FlkDKYqlpaspSfVdvgcuCvxS47FSbpTos5aQcXYdAcIxYaoSuNjw68NcGKEP4s3Fe9lxPNRnk0gOg/D4Xer4BQaacSVUwIeUXFqjFmq6ltJxdw9O8q3LNKOSZhhTW6tUXZ9EaHhNpFDKsMbU2zl6wiAcqdSmSPDtL8sEBZmRKePD39XW9vv/4Qb2eRFF09sg9mv0fHfXDr2v/@0fuoyO378L/0dHRI2ZV4vfi6j34lCvxHfG4G6mU7p4VVWy3vqiIJHfunlXSKrpzcWj9BvrFP/AzgwjPysaZFGWgqVyWSB8qXV6ULkvkCF7BUS8FEUQ07gDPktCjwKfkK1SX8Lm4JE/8Qefls7PAxR3JZ5dnaBeAwRf8g8IZfv0H@Lf/3/X/6CmLVWug38Surndi9FHwT1Gurq@uxW9FicXES2wH/tAD3jHJ1XUFnRTpClzVmFJTrq@5H/zGlB0OsIJ57FQo8SwiNP5IkCfly39i/7BPzFt8zvBA6dBM/dnZJJVSSg3/AFucpTLf0ISpUqLrSDYbVb32pz@mY4rvKhQpmymV9C3GX4yMUSpl/LftfKmU9182Y7HCzU8ldVfPgYKTyShKqQQvd32wKXgNwOYBrP@SBaiWZzap3ZciV4dHdIAviIlsRMESccEQS9E533hlRFQuynfuxMQVjnd3lTt3jELqzZvAZzAAL33Oq15v2cN6Hf3Tb97IdZlmzgtZeE/l37wBWRZV3GHsMd40AhnFVJ19bFQoz4I7BEJsQzDTk8YMi67pmaPRMPbaHiRkXGHiyQpdBJBKucOz6M@@@81vnkXLZVmVyTejIwDMhWV3dnKZSiWXAXcuD5SSN6/4nRideEFXrjeTMqcGkzejERGk57cVLhujGA49HLtbgQbu4YddXUeo2lkmq8RAuiqgaF1H8I9764UC92eZXCwfL4i/8obCKqAD8D@0T9PxzNb21r0ao7/Jsg@K5NKVVdavy1dWEYf5rktNcT0abkmz7txJF4Cm@VTpTKrXH@ye7tbrZVmWsTuEH/Qk4S7h7TKDYbRKFZ4t1KpYvtpZNFos3SPm0PNZFomWRDw1Cr0EyxeIDJLdxv2mUHZJF8b/hmTQE38kMRa0AZ54gzmbfZ883N3bP00YO6DSGAe7ewnj5On9iI6v2dk7Bafx/Xh/98HRU0jw5OH@7sn@J4ef7z99Av4eu5x9fAksfmfPsGvJ@yV7Jr0cvjYty7TGllW/HI8vX7GXtl23gbC9sW3bbmfIPKtuWdYAovmfEnybtme@fGkOB/Rh73747Xc//O/e/ei773707Xc/@v7Pvvz@t@H7E/h@lz@/@@8KWfz92Zf/4nff/c6PwPM/wfeP4PvTn335m9/gX3r/Y/j@l5DfH4tvKB7/SgDrV3725fd@/LMvf/UH8P1X4vuDm99f@@ny7/e/tfqL6b73u@vjfPffw/f3OCw/7nd/h/vh80b83@HxfvUH737jP/D/PxV/6PzRu9/4Y/wRL//8B3/6X9598z8aRv5P/@27b33v3be@@e5b33n3rX9qvPvNf6unwj@/@@77f/BXf/h7f/WH/xP9/4R@f@99/t/94J//xf/6F//7X/yh@P4Uvv8BXD/9i/8IDPu3f/BD/P/eH/ztH/0Q///nf/23f/Drf/sr/4Ycv8Ud//e/@nf8969/7T//zW9/569@@o2/@fWf/s1v/cFf/R@/@n/@5n/@6//@9//6f/wmev7WT//qj37lL7/57b/81r/8y29@ueL322t/v3wP/y//EXzeH8/3gfM@5fpQny9/IXz@PtSY5QJ8Atz9z9795i8Dg/8GY@@@/RNcWAnfFf8/MXSK8xP@9v8Bh3GzzBiSAhd8f/3dt7@LJPofgETwH9DrO8HLXAh/@c7sBcj62wuJIlZxvvPMG/n4FlgYW4WC6ECD4B1K@bMv/@WPgyx@eR7qXBjk@B2UVHNh30EZ9@6H33j343/67oe/9e6Hv4K9mZopJHYTqr5@8Bm6QDX7HvEwYu594kHEL76A/CdxGipV4/jGvhCBX3zxhTR5k8SVvPfegO8X5MU/jAdBGBNBfpjwx5Wq4TjcmfKdm@j9Jpw1kiGO2cZJFdjy9ZRsmk3i/uAhjsTxQUSMNNni44n4S74YPJHwZ/Y/c04kFsc4/IPXovhOcoh0IgvulLKQTXwyCY1ekvpBGHIfmkWifDMFhiWYTOITsEjBATnEIeh@nJXL5TgmLHN84JWjVskzQiUeL0O5MTVPk6jnEcTkPkGBlOX4MatvlSc8YRzhVXxyxCX0OpZ1Q47nyw8gw/LkAUNYCJzAvnhRruTLkwqCe8vpEZ/E7xNOCKwcn1TewnuZYMZxUOnBW0AlX47HK3nMEAvJqydR55WUpcJR2eMsLuoAnjRCe4@xj2U9L/MZjQ0kGI@Nv/FZ7Ls0x3YXws/iW6I49O876btFBN@grEQujIffJVXxLtceMQLAVVVN0xh8VRWxuQfBEw4qTtnCI84hxIkjiAMCD2BDrIs41W@cXiD/SHnrgz/xisRLs7m5KUUqclo@ohmeOFjtw/Miv9fiDTeNikzOFWT0tmjlNy@dtfmEhh22HmzBrw7/@xu0IDvOSoTWZhQH96KM58c@jvPvvXtb7GMoPT1nfhJT42k3g4PrWNCdeFw2INeKG5eeg3STgH0J0BtJm5RpXikuJRKMaeUIhrGjoyOBGnk8L0tx4H4jreM7TgSMx@MIpNC0hJZIiKdGT/LQhEOjUPHUNpHmNBjJDCNTAvumxNCLhc0RHexW9Hz79i1UFi3KKB6CRcnE@gwjk6dA8OAbHHu9qb8bwMgUJG5OMz3Hb2yO0cV0ClMkFmNbisSX73IkguneqJHPR9GlQJ1osS1/uU5Ol/wxQhoiDFJwGy@fVfzAvSO2d/To0f7j00GtxiSLbgy06oOh27Q8b51gjmG63ccP@Op@o5BDNCLVKuZ8WjRQLEn7xRQJzcMHx4cnRcZpImooFkBSSjT@K0hR0KXIYPBsJyKWNMh4hYUrn@BvcVb@mFFIY4aVkhRpWmiWAMPhPytJj7zOfXcCtnxClhN6Dk00hUZQmfQ1t1gsv9Uz2xI86X3M8Eglvv8SWieuAdd2dohoUuVKpVFvdEIF56RKRawNYrpUOdk/hQSnR0w3UhoDS/8qs21kspmskc7lstuGnskVMrlsPg19TS6VNQy9kMkU8oXta6nyBZtoiKsK7l65ZzmdUXcTV@TIZyk5RI/NaiqBf0Y6Db8AMaFnt2sbG70rFRE8I7a4wqVV1/B6pSIFPoIPkz6S2EfgBR/IA9dLMbFY7fCoJFYM4UkHMb5sSNaz0LgV6QwYiYOTBuFPyXdAKwKbP/SVIhtf//qIVSpga6uHB1IEhFWX@YtnVLuldTVip9Z4aFFoh7GW/bmN95toLdsb9MwpNNGUJkWur6/bAOnwAGdW6ZWnaOHvdZN8GuC@npjS///5h/zsDCrApjvJQWWHHwfEcLdhWR5ZEzx9jPvJFc/qtTXcB1CWKYUh74iD9yqSSFjBHRWu2SrjnjQ6vQQaq3LVKrfcJt2bVGppDbc11bzRFESnYIBytNFzm@dRP9DG6yhxg1XZyG2rohFAA@APNZ/IJ7IJo1ZlMbkox6s1ulZL0XhDUjc2gOsss6XCs@06I081CrXrMKqYdwVzSmAJrwQWRcd1rOui2Qb5fNXkC9mKspHNy6Vqafa@nZNLtet7fatlm7io/Sx1dSNNLiVf@1HOUhhrSZwcxAGsCBlpR5w8VKGlV1UQFrV96AOqtR3/TCLorSXDUI20mtZVPY3/tzgM/H//@Ab8G/gLqdKGdIr78h4DYUEoOuwhHo48ctmp69I9WPet5ooYe12T1pjtDV3P@3vEuW865zzogc0PwwmCPjXxAHyvb4@6K2I8HfRxS581/EeDsN9vAILI0jzCffgZ9lx3WYRt9vTJilI@Co6fA2Lw8@cg@vHhJ5@ehp6n@7t7n0o5dv/o8YOFR1ZEyrKH@wenwes2D/WTZgMQX9t/@HDxVTwi2H3iMOgGy277Dl3CRap3wHi4I5zZ3MyZQuczvn/K9oJFk3yjXFE69TdVmQxbX8NiTb7LEq0ZOgFBKDX6dkGSBsxxL9l2irXcXs/EOwDbG@DZNXGziIXddI@uqsSsL91hr3Vpt6wN6RHuSynoeNEZIiF9CkD64yZtN7ZHEp6n08Lb@XDYvYEXjI/xBswVnvBAL3QO7U4XJOGl60eQGqbJ4PuhH0hvhT@j9R4jngf53Qjp3YwuRSTUxsyRGcmX7tzRnwyBsyv5VLE4ancs0NgHXmV/AuzFxuwpMLw5RNG3mWSbWTnXlA@YVo@YW6ACdeyqVxscszwOBjfNdGYLFFIde3PQwkxrO4LSEnSQBEMtsWqAJnKWapTNVsYFpUEeyk7pNWhOpeJf//ZPkI@3kiCyIros45LZDV3SSMUzCvlsvpA2QIoX8pmsnstmE7qRAA16u4AyXs/ruXy2oCfymUI6AzoThGYL21KEr0dKbhFIeBYBrNPE@7l2SEvUuhUpwudi2OuYqbCIGbyPmWxBGhlvZPZGtCdvyy7LRobpKQYGAkA0WZNFDg72UgcHsnwfX3AGei8lyy18yeZTqe37smxRyF4euz/Z5WnyeJiBPOIvqdT9PVkecwB4DqAsd/FlP4fjC7Js48ve7sEB5tPGFwPTQ7RzHsJfev7LNkRz8CWdpgEKWX4VgIN4uzyjDGG6jy@YJ4Yc8JA9CJPlT3x8UimAcMzjcQif@mXd3ZXlQ/6yu4she1TwLEf1M3zZpY8sA39gG5HlDjg6Q2idstwAJ7YUWW6Cqzk1wQ9vQ8PD4pyRKctTTiAkkSxPKLbZPJfBCBf@mM2nn35qdkctq8M/0yF/NgE1CLEn4/2DxiefNDqdxnC6u//JMYbs7X1qtqfjYaPTEMkadfi4kAZCzvvTxQ/geFivm72lIZ9BiLMQUp/WLcStbr4CnMSng5n063sQsgchy6axODT49CFqAz/3@/C8bzYoxP9QCD0njYZcQkZFDYyuNIU2Q7eLJvpmc@iW8H1S3mAsGosmptVcqlaiANYHPStVuqa7TGN0hTwatMrVtDopp2rlSXnb4Osf2jH5bGJkbTmx0b@rF7LFDfOubmTikyLuzHXbURZV9bsspt/Zes1ij5W7RjpTlM/u3lXlql67a@j5Ym77@dZYlpUi/t5NbxchYioK5h7@KNXt2t3tbCjJ9nbcTBrF7W2ldA3kGEFP2kARUo/FLi3zXFEQXTRLoAj8JtUpldMutWOTxKTM8WJTpTQp6yV@jhFL3YDVwkPzxs2RO@QQOwBucjdVpLtaZb2QlyH/ZDKmKCCZSIjAc7a66dlXT89PT78AmQUGnzCXnvALAEvi9ZNP9zSwoMQbHnanHaCi6w61PRQscyH8LDbf6xRkp/YpdIegCft@uFti6Pa0/QkYsagt@wH@EUaaOHhGO/10Ds4J2Io8Z9xsWqLTC5ymxfAsQLvFzHIFXGYLzHQSd6ZySR1xvVIp18t9ft1qJUj1Gb@vfgbm0OO4B1tgKfkV7iAQAfVy6rrUKE8iE4BTLzNVf9F3Wy@MuF5q4RGA98v3MXGpDs9GySpbeOmsHJFL7bsOWN5jxzPb1hNriBu6D482obfBbQWxNrOUTXZGV9TuodZ8rVaGzJlh9njcj5lqpaHMe4VekTSxr/pFvqJ9LjgxfF1ql1nsuVJ6Ba/DTRZrafeVu5lSK3af1RXwSb1ov2gzg@UyJbq1K4aQoBERbejqV6Vc@Qw0GQ74vFgEREQdnwNMzAnA2i0KMJWBfV3qlKsY@Q3@7KiyXFPV6puaVFHVZ1IFmmVpGjHL3rhBx8SyVEM3UrnSBPz07UypyxrlxvNJaVgegPFc6kG1iqECvnvHLAH1gEgA5vWb2Ltf/oayo2bL3K9EoN70QFeoa/XypOTgMcTAAeV0GQLi1Uwqkc2DMZXdTkD/a0CvnkukE5mEuo2@OllY4KlDHx/rxWTG5ERqktL0hG5B/x9LvbBbL5iSOI@BmkEUgpeRu48X3IIP1AkyIb3C02RK3NjqgSnYcpm5oxJXgmAoYcGAxF02sBNdBHVsmT1KoSgqS2/FepsxjLN5Oh7sV2vF4v5k8FUIiqmv7ubi26n4a0UpxTaUsme9kiolqYJChEo92AAWFaMozBv3q6mNnJ64UuvqNVTuaFPfNorVagPLup2CQtr1N50duSLXGNTRNROKCwoIrrvMtI@ZXx21ZbwumukFoyRptGKAstRjRmHVvg9FwrVqAqA0EMINScxiZ7K/gS0WjW4b0agSLeGA64YsxslAovGbp0G0Ru/od2XQl8AGLhgYYSYYaY9SKqwyXUto5bJMQYpcSddX1ztgTiZp6Rhof2yDXKpWuSdFioyB3nYmTsFIbjD2oSvS4juV5/x5hmtWAa5EJ0dVWY3WiVg22kDsc9yPeZdFATFz2K8aRrpWNaAyoBwtP6ph6CUcTo7g4litApT3rgC/nXgFtzJ8xqZTM676lL3DWCe@KVGhI4tk3y3vdo53S/7bHg5lnUmyLJeicuQqGolew58UuUf7Jwy@f4JFQjso@JrLpgX0eRshCcH2rvxhjiLebBAzi1weVGvK28d27yqfVrk9DwLq@jqymaQaEcvQS5@9MLJQR47rr0sHuwY1bOiqslkcjoskXwy8rxv59KPDI@fB8MDyF6Bm6nIlwlK6iqu8S0Xhm@XLUuVC3pCN80SE3YuUIuxcjepFWrrOBieF59vP888fPT16enQgRc423my4OFTLfLKwt85XvgoRo@lMlLGzcmRSzpTE0qBKRdV3DHYXbDWG14e39ZyaelPh7FuhgJwBIe9@@QeZyU4e3g3QVotQhdm4UanoWwZTIoN3X/4@Hixwtf/57kMW9cwp@7s/@bGx/Xd/8q9pwU30uuTRgOB2BGKiU89tR66uBldX1/DhYdlILcKRymwr4OZj0Hpktjq@mDTNre14xrjnlJIirr6tKxFPjYiR9u1sxHsjgoxUHoL8oXDyknNYBZH9Yztr6Pd2kCn0YFMNm824Wl4BuCL/6MUbxuClWWl1OrZBrmSSFd@qbOetusPe4lDyW3WDvShXcPpTx604/qjpVqVSQSgsWoknt6LMyEJY9bpUizMadQUj77m15WydzXP02QYrFBzwt7wtMVh/tuWBIbfl0J@15Xnw6r9ZWy89JuN0QjLZatGJKzsWy1ag/reSgM6Z8u6Xf9Mwcn/3J7/2pv6m/oUBllqhkNONyM/1n/8cIqzZA@6bWTS0jJu10RGYZ2zFVbdaEyxDvP@4zXh831hD8wx1BLvjgB2Ob9IF6jVUNXV@sFArRtG2cItogrRkOvZDKUlSoE2SFjzsNBMEg23hYePQNqUr6SMMgt6UlUFcSh/NQIFHH/pPt1n3euPhgJacxyidXkuwO5AEcvgIT2LaoK2tQuaqIKaSWzeTcpQ9ohrpQKxveR6e6wS9iPQRJHkIbE83mLGBibuwMabtgJDXMArhSQGtKuRdg7x7PEGdfGNUeh4hwTh2PJEDmrL0EWgDRAUblARm70CEEgiWj4AAUIaYAGzX2A5LK@zKjsdLs0OjrnH5Lh6OZfo7QCVMhtBauOPYT1zCeOAFGjpeUoJ8IWoY1LGQpw@Ew@DTi2XQ8TE5vaGSRVu03xsUwKLjUGJUNHbnzgyrctluKYxKhPDP7QGONlE9OMtxBWC@ffRxqygnmBOPY2V/NM92QPE4oQtcp/JzuEqhpEzG12tJgv/3ZlrkyIWqooASFkDUF28VTSAZJEay8zpssp0y041thQXINwH3JiFFh0UFRt/Z5GPN@MIPvAYMfx7xD/oF6XMaHsETfLu4BZhBtzfGU1bxIBguDMTWXX7UC0qxw5GfOkgFRbF7FLttD8EgoelN/9yoWFpXMNnsnC3CgxbkGhmGK2OzCj4oFcZm8DTxhCSRzwad8tB0oUK9gevQkUp0/AMuOgaOABklTqbhaI@dSzyVW9QNJQ5j5NGpNMj5iDEdEUUXnVFanC9sDMFq9WmTYFZHY81@ixkFFiNGoxN0nACcQokI4YaFh5kN3UbP6gNKJ5bF8FQhr5hMdkArGjfoGKFHNvBV98CGrsTxkuJOueSlfW4nT/FUUdVtgw4tNmVHUJHC5senJsWRPT3XPWc9@9ziA7OxuS3tHgOFH5TWBFB29gXCFnEM2EgnWAqCEzwWfLfhsc2d@UQo7UZsqtx8pvWNWB1r9A31SfYQ74u7MJ0QfenzRhImrTf1/EMx6GgHeNcCkWuJ7fDlKO7EDc55kMTxHmU6WULDwflBDAxM/1gMdIIubl0wNE4l7GNAaDb9DebYiqG0H1EHQG0PWhaekDUaFvFYBMBk2Io1oekJAe@wj1nakOieHjqzRJwvAjCw6svz0CEMkmI5vFELKkbjm5lArkDr7LcgDDfkCvbD9D53o5tOL5uxN9sQ4LDTobzKjDcL/yUbesHWgfxMRd@AwBxguASTjZgcB7BxWZE56CD9YnLO7RLJkiK7CSnBEIIgNUAhVcG/UJKFjs@WIOC@6fEzFsVZWpeXlxod6jYe2prl4ZHSHt6SmRx0bNCJ3eTI6g/E5T02Xucm4M5cKj9JHu9OvTuhW0sLd6b8KUltrywWEsSibS@KneMFnpjc6dNhMHgKi0cMdWDTaevNmFj7wPnPqCWufP4rIv@p@eg1AmEMwUwS00QzAcASjeZ5on3ZKomAC2qQABxq0fI98RzFof/S93yXPWgHMdwRLfH33xu986bbc1EnkflQ6SxrXkI/5tR/Fe8DewKJHOuS7Q6H5jRG4QrGRgaOTUntYVPo9ikEnNDNsCt@qp89qU5rc8knQXLo1IKZ3SGe9CJdrQfKj3jE8AkPn0D4hIdPZpn62VYnNa6Sodc1Fge5Hg8I82MimKkf55ofhzgLIcigWDOdg8CY0zm/a/g2y5Tapzd/g3os@4wBPDEAgluxZPX5WfWs5njW5VYtnuwAs8tECKhxAF2tEU0vW4Ebqd@76A1cb87LwXPhoFcSeKNXsyu4gfMKljGoIGIMTi8bj/Lq9MXkNlcIRIEBAuphEIiqwe4oZiul4KBQCgTGqcozGnPEqgKZGmlfIkj4gbrESc8JGwZUCwFC/6BIgCaEML/l8AsEfOnwbIg3KPtxVTrzvI9HykRrUaDkQlPhsqZElRTCSlV9NIHsqK6WF4vih0NVVBeCQsW8FvUfRn/jg9FvQ7tYjj0xLO8wSlK4qeDKKlAhRHMhqrJKOVSvgEFyy@xZQ@i59rl@KnpryGYr6ZsZPB8sgneJ9yXGQpXfVHj90KYr2ZGLAStMy2Uo4rTMmyVvFz5JOcGDZJ5INvUZQaTnAgRgpJYms0SySTjZpFzmgoNNViS7DCE5ISQnPAmPPVmBZE0kA@spuGgXq6cG2imu45IBns67UVCDBjLDSxNxDvolHneFs5Iiz5nMIS4QPIQqNvJZs7Y092oI6ZDQWgCAjHgDQIvfRVSUFgWergZvgYzipPRlFH8TbMBlBTAYieASPxIyFjAZ2cCg8Mtx6geg7crxqiTrNLCLfyn@lRO@p//Vb3qm5mPq857@0pzg7x/Fs4aUDTXQkPahpzIokNGSeSqul57TOSJ4bV/XBa2ucemy2BJlG/yT/s3UyUbPbST7Jq77wBtKgvuqFd9@wDkQdm/gjsyRm8kUudFkE9sty5/bDHbHccE0CR8FC7pey7U8JzqCSm26Hcf2rATekM1VdotWIfCzqKWwniycridJYgySm7EImvMVqrr1Ot6ZVq/HcMmWUgyWgNIKLmTPaFRC@xdcofQgngTQo0HMbby0miPldph4arFIdmo3z2NHAxEYhUx2GciwJuj/ENoFDYZ57sxypPNTUZVujGJ04nnX7bsd0PrGniZh6gXwhzPYiJA5GBAuCWaiSVsMHV1NrSTWTJiKSPrZBydlnxkxUwnSG/MA5oiRYMNFGiNlh0uyq6/Mjifz8zv5cHxPwvierMeXrPBFnLlpXuaBH5Z1OjaDABFnaKRvRwOLDnKrdQOdOVQCb9SreIL3RrFF66paiOkuRN0V0bU28EciePPgLUD881X0X1@BfvL9960@Ey@SPJmCvOnjcr8YnUXv@ZOZMYh@qChSZEl2AWs/eM@8IC5eA3KAKgSosSS4HDz6ERrmAMxuLziQ3Ad8C8/j8qgbfE9rpso8cAlOw4sEOzdWV9GDesvqmVOrFRMxEyG4fomPwWAjefV@BUdBR0LP5bZeDPouJQiFbhyJziMVV7CMmbhQlNVsxaPYAffQSDlheLiafhh@QzTjEF@Zj1aDHRCN4jFkzoWNw5@D6WDKTxfu0RHovhzl/Q@vSdxafjtBgA7icJXELFtlnfg8jgVFeo8eIYirzRcZD//0IeK5mjfr8MNIdHtJoXJDicp@LUvzJ@Uvr3F7XY2HuMLnST5v9H4seRvTvTfPhViNA5uJsL0P60JuQMb1F81mLAyR@6ytMde5IRPQj8bpnBW9Sn2JQA1SkqQb2WRuk36hSGgZH8ITB5w@hycC7FijOmcov2w4piXu9mAU0jcHIa1F@ICSDlBCVOQkF2iEYkm@G6JfXQd5Nlfm2byRZ3Muz6AFzGcZiiQ157IUtYDVs64KelZ7tEI6YxDazvBYJ7bh47jmEEcrrqJ2tGgnWPQiWgSBHLWixf0YCOVoK1p8QA4vWjwhx3m0@Bk4Zm0r@iZa9JsFRhjCKznuob8Q4fjejBb3Ysq1NDLPLc/PV4sWgzqFOHf5K1EESIHlBq0Rp9gcVxRzNLSgYyOlMsGQY7wEmk80DpOgbwr@@d0XdIY@BuIY5xZFZnGmz3UaoR6D5wPdhn9G85KWXBS9@f7RAa1fCqJgNnGw8cJpCDyo4ZHovDDiiGEozWjAExBEuVlcjhEL9WTviY7IHTiUKnk@f6KeRvpAK0bhVYhcm2VCF56I9H59zYPgFfh@eGLiVXjeQMfPjjDCOVllCVpI1BfRNYXCup7HRdR@uIZorHs@Et7E6kfhtURgQzIddDianMPMBu5gnkkoFFe82@E0NCjHGyVy70IykgqiZa4IJm9RMhQM4cavrCtOKB2iNieCMLCaqvFWFvQLJIsxaCbrQpoqb3yAQkjmQAu3mud0mcwD4aR4XNwkqK9Y1Q35aXmWJLnmxSQk1vCMnLE54rkHxus@npzzYearn3KCYy0xBBBKGeTC5av7Afq7y/V3X6H2ibCQwTLFenlXelO9XtvLLmDem2V7swIxMMEeKEuVoyCHGcnBOghp5ut47YaKj0s@uJLPMw2gL2j7PtkCm@AWui3aFhwWagnDi3nPcwM8z43VhLqpkfQuNF9p0TAnAYcXPMB0VrT1uPKCL6tiDKHxbbP3wRU8nK/gcOUhPCrAcIHkvJUPxw6tcpm1bRDb3AdFql5kXJDTdGlQzTNPEPc0dRtM24LHUf34wdHjh1@DTnd7e1sRffR0hh@2WhxrDfpxDpkWQwf9wRKzxUjg/RA42Y3D8XTr8caZI9@QJVxYgzJgQi4@@4k2rghZFpLnC20X0vG4IYoKWOezZmDOSSVUdUzssm1B1xEQxBrFtkwBxFdvgd4JstYUugmhXsebbut16r7qdVy8VK@LXgyrxp8RV34e2UiOvSHdtMev8biUJNrczh4csWef7p6y00/32cHTvc/Y146esme7j09xk/KTp/cfHu4x@O4/Ptln0tzySLzyCA1KoOsDq2nhfXN4wFiGEeQ9dzDlcie2p3D/E7PPPnWbFk5T7Xhm/16Xv2iONarwVPtgjk5xDNOma6369gjXW9CdTGDGonLToh11uHafQdwG2LR9tHn7bstu2xBXQtt3YFuev7GL9WyoQZC3/l7SBFeS8PolWjpEF6XhCqxLSG5CfJy7ATAmX39FlwnbHk9gtTQmCBd8PpiCp/vHj04YboPfO3r84PD08OjxCTs4OobXJ187fPwJ0PPw5PT48P5TDKKIj44eHB4c7u2SB0cgpTHciP5y7I3WoqBhdKJK8xxnvunO6OBtftQbNXh2adLeQo9Fxw5KH9vs2a@tVrQkjT1UX3A/I00VsNjm7vEnn0Ofz6xXOMPpTwXT@gP5qUfXgG2m2A7lBo2lAu2tJJordHuqrtB8RH/K8FYAq0R7zmPkTjAfOC3iadkWk/dwjQqOffOt6dSWfdCQ0QbARlD@gpUyo9s8otHEDoGsQG7NnouHC/Lc@CJC8YJJ7/lLTUoSUUyslUGguD/h0MHxIL0UeADfg4chsh0NeQSWDjx4BJbhHqiKHuLaEZYVMcajozGKZ5bjHi/7gwOaFmbbgcd9k6zYvMCJ1xtVqcmC25Bwo36P7mzhozx0l5zpNW2bkngUH@8z6fV4w7D4TVogE/lUIq1tg5gyCJs2TjWIZW/8IkkMBW7AdUJme@SxWFnR2CkuDrIcm9@W0@mZDl8CNVu6Q7zH8ngUS1kss7WDW2Zox8fAJQbEG67m8QjSPRBaofW@6SDl/Rs5mmKNJN305i9Buw2B@zcQ@EXAACB1ztJpUk9FW0gRjNsWrBzzXOBIHLd9G44P7NwaN625BGLVVuyl/fq1IoicmLOT/HWKhB1U0WtrCGolTWW23SG0cRKrdC8HSsFm1x2MbF6HsfkS0IwTdXMQGzs2yO1FuTKXG9JhMUfHdUKZNoCLV@TaAKZ8n1yJ4/nceSC@Zpc0AudDJ8zX3SE6ZgPvTJ7NnSVwEunSwuEXUIRprhwHP6cjwoTrn9JMdrxleM9bvlx5cP9MffsigZe9cbHA71f0Fx3iFxgT84LmQfN8tGBxiHqXaGn@JT3euIGpxRo8IS2xlfvAwA7s2mDX3auXgjC@3PimP26SWfQnzzdvyjyVipJJXLnpdWMz6ZZgVT/LBKWpMbEEJCQ7AVmQ9THfJ0EwA3l9D7fDYC2UgCIOyhG02xeuwBEixC9dY9wGySJuIhTVHcBXWIVWVMwuZsWdLeH6SD6P3S/HK0pytqCEhcgZ80V0woesK0poWQr1VzfAPVgPDuT3@4PLr8WOdw8fBO3BWmgfhJsaXw2Ld0shWO8P9u0asLxz@4XAQtkTqwHzTvImtIDTA@ZMbEaC1bTrc3xxo@6o7QEY7HtxBCUAGspt7NAUtX@Ub4wnUMJgZgrRyemD/eNjJnP7BNKC3EOToSXEIMLeYE9mq21th4SdFihNgbEcKE@@z9yKNv@zrjEvJd4KUSF0kISgRyAsZlcQt@0Jl3qiZyEVglbfk0D0KTeP3ZUvg7yqAHwNNiAgO6u0UAGlpcWM8M7H9sKLwAXdElw3Dq/hpxXWvO/G@/2G0zCg8Jogs4M7S5bX3zOuHxf9fLiCZb0aU4FboElDfwN2wglkPICImjZfg2uqxa9SXGTPFeyITztc@JWa17D//gxFjMSVcK4Lh8S6UI4Falw/3vTVHFqQiN2AiSs9RSBf0QwBvognn51whSqzTi823wWBkok3vt0LcwUkr12XgivIY7N@shwo5OG2tknYVH0sazg6K2CXVkf6GNdC5xbFw2JWIG3XZqX@w2TFe4m5nHyaLy2MHwiQc9ls@jbYi6Xwk6t/X9i8D1mUn6P@AOz7GUhv6tHwPnDu4eOEHz5jgDWk40vr/QazkBBUnSV9ylzZqTMK4we48HEhQAaP0MZL9BZzVdhkAbfl0HmPFIZOUW6UIdSEg4LyVnOD@tfrs0OBfGt@Gx@eH29sGAmXDl7jqvxH7tCzZrvyQqemhLxw/@q8nzUcOhSN72fqI5QYbWNau9mOdtvxBa@8VBhI823hkrTF7iS@7DbhjzVQJjS8qOG9mTi6V1oc3lP1UrioB4cP99kWHW3XnhuLlIeyEpI9G7azDgGSwTQugd0H7eH72CvCF3BI@CCBTLSbL0a0UW7FjSgCWnOVrjURy0KFbNUXa7/tNU0Hj/BIyB97TE7cgYQ0Crt/dKAsG1lPlebSA3LewIlBqoSsajIlBT8c0EVI8yB4baJ/qMPCnRr@Ssk1t52bST2fyhUkKp2T@H@Ku761NJJtf20/RQVMpBUaMNEkImZQMWG20WzRZPzQMAgNsgeBoVFhoufb51ycFzjn/jzCeZX9DvvqPMU@67dWVXU3YpL55mK8kO6uqlWrVq36t/7VOH1Ve32eXm4WE4oW30b/Krge3bZ@6Qwub9qqp4Z/u5g0p7/9qtTaC/Wc6lp9JmFN8@vFLMeEfEn/X6nXOeZcjeAbDtF6llDKkxvWlFpS4Tm88ETJ7WJ8aN6Ah8QMl6rlK8OFcLEbF69q6@fFfjFXuKr1zwtw8huvFMcr@ZUUPjyjVZTmGNHM18bnWFOjUle/f6Nw8SZfkKZdQxS7htCX941Rd7BfOngbk8ZhAwARmLb1ZoG63Jm5AGs2@J54ff82pcVkaQWOdbBBchbYKygPn3aWJ0Mc0@oSZtQradrNBhP@P3WdhZx3PRwPOMVEwgNrqbvunbNg3JhyLFGgLLXuuUFnk@GEeVJQDMnXqVhRZ/KyXcvDd9KNgKihJE@HibNEAj6FQFT7ctXOncDzG81LIIFLYu@4mNrc5CtjidUCj6V4MOVojNhhIneORyhA6GfI2gZUwTv3gN0@HGo@3vN4kC8soxqznwwbyDu8U0QKzL/VF/Zv4vKbRAAh/ILsuTwt4tQ7L9pIiu8gCxcQZyx@8IeaAW6V0ikLaCxgS33FEDhbijONUK0mE31fuAU5hVb0p1uQyfPbg2bY/K5kZ5Kwnlq/BaAldyknbeGnFxZLRYplTDGTOUKKhW9SA5IuOh6992lYTdWO3@sR0kKLhZAceGT/Xl3/iq0/qKHOc4u8pGcepGdi6Z6kC1JhLo8W@DDTRjRTIvklzHevEmG29IO6ioo3Lx71dNOjLUmYt/C1vIE3HtS7YeYt25XClTZhM5aQiaR8ntP7kvIkVsYyuE2vSbrm71Xd8xbLWN4f4vXj19Ed5LPxrLY1meFSr9/tvZFFy6aAzRJETaWkOPqb2U4GpfbB1NMJ7eAg5@dhu1UMoazkzYzDYyaxtflDwtObjDepWTTEi/HBwJozRiJU4jpXmHATdlikejj5SQQEwwSjKTNyt0zhqS48jYBFriemWvGCfDDAqWmzQ7wIv8g7/DODPY6cyZecn7ggmE@k8eLdHCcQT7pPEvPJFJ9N4C4iH3WjvrKKhHVPZyHOnyQOIlJgW6cvPthtiMGf2HkiOlGYmeIB3W2KpnSYIW/Y97EuROK986/ssvO2QXvsYc@fqBKOGQ32wnJiDu5jPxgHiOXEsWiC6@GwB60jb/hu2YVaBwpZXYO6JYQYWdk9pwLLHsmfxpN2SKdCnjoE5FsYiIQJwXWnA2cyeMAObjG1QuLSHXtOqT8VgQaNmeer4mbuq@tAtKZ02u9EkZCek9EDSgfDRtP3HNqjBbT7caSpbRnfWp4OvxFEC6MlbcNx/nrdbf6y8xb63Jf53PN8hGQ3Wh2c856/CB2siEgmYTVH29i1/AvHieiGm6IbzgBgWu1jof9IvOnf@P2@75RoxeCMAW1aA39047c8xznyrRIYcMHK0EzCD3twPWqKcIc2XQ1iRngJB2lRhxGH4Rfrs6iLm6wrSztQWoXaZurqm24LBDQeJ@0BtMOssECYAKEHCl35YyLKsqviKLHuWePCe5crCKKIGohzEtFNWDL0B@Nuk3qGJVlOj0CJGiSsrN@awYTqa/YacA725iEA95iQAgYBo0r6Gg6OVpr/LhyUbpjRsTdMz2Rp9hvwWKHh7o@6NPuGBOZe4WIR3KmDj99Vqqp6uHf8qXRUVvT84ejwY2W3vKu2T1nHDUU5B6xV7w73aXax2nTRmh/Sh0SpSiUTnOCUDk5V@acPR@VqVR0eqcr7D/sVgkbgj0oHx5VyNa0qBzv7J7usfScI6uDwWO1X3leOKdvxYZprNcWcsJw63FPvy0c77@i1tF3Zrxyfco17leMDVAatfkl9KB0dV3ZO9ktH6sPJ0YfDalmhYc5upbqzX6q8L@96VD/VqcofywfHqvqutL8/09DDTwflI8VGApFWbpcJy9I2HWFRE7dzt3JU3jlGg8KnHSIeIbifVtUP5Z0KHso/lak5paPTtAZaLf/1hDJRototvS@9pcY5qW9Qhfpl5@SojPhHoET1ZLt6XDk@OS6rt4eHu0zravnoY2WnXC0oZ/@wygQ7qZbTClevcdUEg6hF6fS8fVKtMN0qB8e0Zpx8gL2DS538iQhDWJao6C4TGGYQaC0R6fDoFFBBB@6AtPr0rkzfj0BTplYJVIBFxc5xNBtVSEQ8jjZTHZTf7lfelg92ykg@BJhPlWrZpQ6rVJGhAoOMU2IdqvSEW41@IrzkkZjVMZyb5u5UlT1V2v1YAeY6N3FAtaK5hcm2807T3EP024gQpTuAzKBxFRWstB9@uvERTPKhRGa@jMZGTNo53C3TiqyDVSXChBNadV7NhFKKptFKYxPpNRaypuVfXHfq3X57AB9TW0wEH1dBJ407TFxc5XDmfOWqCC1f4QLJZL3@sVSng261XnfT31Myhsa3Smgx@NdyubqNiFKPkzcEPxsbQvfNGKG2nmlFJxvqQQGBnEL9Z2L61rjyXZXNtnxdDM77AGxER4GoTS6hSqGpkZ0dcd9EWCVLJvi9q9mBC6YMeK9Zh5wUlpGcaRDQv/5d@CKLQ@QDzc4i7spmcYhlNLq/@aYaqYRDIvA/HZGg2@YqvcD3f@mkctHqcOb3OoNBK@W6pgznHdM5sJNyv1H8wu/MFM/MlmdkWe2sw@MH5tzNWxirf9YkU7pfvBG3LIV/9TH/uAYbifkAqSlXxcJqLbRMPZPisEhKKx3aAu4V3MnY870v/VT5hNNcbvVFYeb7O/tdxhbsBRF0lha8Gpc7559355KBBhjH4iCSdHWEjGw2UsbYm9jMt5TxEpluuy1Y/tBafenzuk4koY3sdaMXrROr8ag7iWJP8/Dbo9L77ZO9PZo6ge2LV2sv1wuODbv1U1p@T1EPR4blqGNDWsdpn8ZJkVGyQxsfHimR2Nkh@zMDZ7PIiODpptP4I@I8WLuNuCUTJjI0N8DlK32Y6CV80CGhOADHE8fw69yRqRkgFWuqi9ZcNSa8xW/QXol5QBuz9KbcaxP8A2w7/M0Qtw3SDKRZjGPlEufS6YLnvcSeMRXlww0H7kEWL2H4WMK4WRqwqIvtZ@Fdy2@atyO9GIgpI8YrdzuXJCSezGKhjF1FX0b2B44zogXAHD2Mvvyk@Y0eT3WAOw531wjGpXGVyLhnS0JOHQqjdaNrGvL5VpG66NkzW9OmgpTf1Ujx2NPiZBsYJDIaGJVzGBUW1Qzggo0jMlslW8D@sOSqL8KpCN4BOAXNsfqdOHdeczSUgokfot9NVAolsGyQE6Hara3DMVlObRwLQ84Ymf4QPRj@n0iTOfA36cRJ0ENqRYIAfhclGarQio6vTJTurVE0RLQbITWjn05DMPfRjrm0DdPam4n41xAJdO9MzYdTDnvYTs0hAJgcgo3o@LUmaZcNOjr9kHB1cehJ@s2rYUrptcIsFQ/gZtbP07ztShvdCl5c5YqsKVLhPhVVP8jB7YJHPR2ZZo7y6mmQEHCuif@RXWYBiB3wzKWXYrU6y1k5PcrMPKBDLUUWnJaNmETb0vtHtXbLKhIiMzb3a82XIRSB3gI@D9vJt3oMlJjnxiMu8kqsjjkKHuJ/45iMxUeHrLtgQ8yeDzhPWywMwcUf41ssED2BzqH6Qmgq9ZQNRVBJaHUYxhnEdOt6RFpeVm8t9iyZBIda7E/6EnjeF6mWyeFJgA@NYdRd3lPvG1NCufd9zRYWyy5XB2nYLqIyEUvo8rjkpDkYjGjr2EC7Ccd0d@p66pMWOvj94Hqk4xfSetYdaYmE2fRTNdg2yemdlxmJ@c6oBd0xvBVaHvMHN@nKh4WohCeZZNZVipjX8OiWETp2Jyt5ldoMUzaJJhyWlIm4qdbV3Z3kEoLqkKE@U7Ab2MMF22xyPdA72OF3Oxj9grUfW6B@y2/ZyKQRkCwLlE6q9DnGY3MsTR8OApZoUFdAAmIpkRdBmjVUpTX6pWYnbdeUCKNjInYpt@T312OZ1FhLUUUh4@raifnWM9SZoNKqDg1qg4XmV9cYlXkHrvtHD2McLTSutlaJs76dUjZkE1F8araOeJJ50z6d4kkL@YtPA4we@gIdt96CAmHsWaFXfTjPMX6wKfjU9UetqEyUdjKtxhDiNz76DPrMi0Z0qMP@NRvjwJ/SCaCZ7U6yDKOe@nFw2a/vDHqNTnfQbdA5DXHcJzLj4XHKj@iwzmhwG/D9PZzQimRqTcNniS8jYdjwbvWShUhormDsD1NRM4XxaFq6lDARLDmHEWB4iSLz93A2Rpot82ItLOTE/U/ZHi/vFh4t@zw/r7Bo9AFAT3BbMxYU4kM6ZsekiPNp4UGGi69liOB4oTKq4T5isRfD@DWRiNUwMYwNMg/MEqKNwMnsUYxrrUm6xTEIRwi05O/6uGImSPHndAPX1dIs8gaWAhsq/yoXKSpalAniEOJh@ji5V1/@ydgTAn8A/fzzedwyjxF4imubaEuBnFd0lFHChc0DuzxH80xMs1i3Q6tQLwa0PpmFGk@ePkYNtvyhTZEOs/eAKzEiU3TwwZVwqTpNOfWpi0VlSS25HLcDW5DSOJV7nGH9b9nP8uCHElckZ5iYdjTkVATpx0jVJCrhZs4Z89ooyhJT@dsjZnX1e3tthoDFeSZnkRtoUwmzc2EPlK6sr1BrDUY0GSdmqKdNPZaC8WC49J3Ue3TumBuZbR6tm677TUNgYbYiLZbLLSZtcYrHacGZxWeGaeIUY0sz4iEcX/nZsvksESfFOsZbsT79Bh0eo1loN2UXFdvfLRn7WBRvYNFrFho7pBh3BCkt2O@1OjW8/vgMomHK8arOM0YdU0Z9Ko8RUDNkslT6fgox92ncZ@jRIsqh3hbRLto/jxJ11kjOhDw1SbEgl6AnArfDaZPmpWEbxhcIEyc7XDtJ2Q3nJD1lVV4@c4Egw0gQgNgV@5lQDiUS3LCzZviIbwdop@qwFspjJqKnraiFgw36bwnGUfm1cEdbPNSnmfx5QSBNLCQ6VXCur0Ey/ub0WqtPGMoDUtAQn0MK26IHc9Pl97fqj7aF8hEEKc3J2tI3l0ZjXLVC2NC/aFJ9gj1wWJUuGRtR8YFQ56mBxgKdUjo9X46r2P11R8LxsG7Qw4gOEPI5hZ8VXQLhvNdzltooMmlNkcXV5JbR5qrMlhQJGUreQX49FGWrywdXAuALxlS@mCcICGvK2EMpwKF3opwXQ1T3ERUs5jEs6SNHRQ3tPOekg6g6w4u1SI7cvByvozAyc4HQxmJ@nhAR2rPMzxJCoYVuLi6RHC/ntyfMQRtiw/tCceoK3StxGtqeEwLSI2NrZ5RaXqVzmoM58cWaG0u0/M2pr3OR1NxsKtHHYljL5GdTX@ViqbFqV1fjRWMliR5utNZYIpHCjSJsZ4U/9seuKdGQ59YmNHLIiO0ytH12H0epW5zbvL8FapOdss0ew8CLeoab41ddrliJBWX/egB2tcQqA8Ru/8OtNZapBhN9VwDHpTPOLik5EPKONYGlHs3CSddE2rMBCsyZdtBWH4/39mJhXy@mxtDoyh@t5XI5MPFFNPi9sa2GKKk7yMZzZ9vXvV52ePvj6ONFlud@3FDfCwYb5gTtU5fQoAi8wagjN0MAB8qK3BntyIqz/nW7Hb2CARpKdB51m@TU0RAUL0Bda/Ty8ZgFQAxSL7A/o4Fo38/Kjr7bhmw0NRSjhqLSMAm@SRjtGZEHH9qwz7aaKgaGidlYM9G65Ra3vmAFwc0m3Fkcvtj9EponJ975vd4grT7hBmBECli4ny2wtxctkJMs0DCyd@91wPFo08q/6fYifsXIEuV1gDMLk7lnwsSFR2z8I79TngxTidrnBC0r1OQVNHMF8anTKtFJuDpY/HeAFT4ktL8r91VjmGoynWYz01KvR3D4RBg9z6fnnn1iWVyWiWmafTs3iDofXY@DNVDTXd4LmFj23L3ckkeyW@Imzib5NmiYExgaJ8Rc@b4ScDX786bFm3G7/X2zIl8DIB37u2ZEuQnlj02IrAPgEaiHH9ETUbT/kqFhvTcTUEQ2OLis4@G8gwJ1FHCcp83ir7epUqmkFocrK6pU2qaHTEaVtktqFx@2t9UuvW/j/VlxdW2tIHPurvuFPm6bj/dqm2CwhHOleTnapVdKK8JvDNba6OLFbHExXVisFze3CkG2VtqGWz89/fPf//Of//Ff2ZJ@@R@8bPNL7bPN5HledrH5ZfHZfQHvtd3zpcWL2uLwfKlTAJf9i6OGDyrjTCM0H/VGF05SVoHIV7YjNedsjj6jiypzq99VY/QLzS4bKtkMskn9NZCbo3iOTTb9yHcffpQXdIQ3lw7MHuUJiSQBnUIcT73T9GGAR@sNUZJwgR2olBfdihHcIxyMzWC1KkkdiYf3rDc@fFrCSArwxaUVK9PtB34fEvAb3vNK8xynQb/dcV3zb/bz@6CzPZio5bOUWs6p5bRaTiT4J7/@mr66i9kuvHMlGx0HEok0pYSqBZgZqqDLGz0@P/BdOzPkdpxFvrIHkEyYCs4sXnBpe/pjZxm5cC3oOAu4NFOJiISVTCiS/LLYv6du@UI57hMxVxveKNT1KYYri2hUbP9iC9QIxBAgrPlKCLIxoCqh6WOPZDxlzRfd1w7fJsSAQdajt3s87vGB1qLFvrZ5jp2lcM0Rm8/LV6yNBXGGZrSRIvWHCLBCRY6TOfYkXEouOWLlHWklN1O8sKPt08wntg5Tf2xs06XQv6kIE4g1d5Rwi33t16INuUW9ohJdq16JVJWYtf1WTqTI1XVv3B1qdwWuHQPqi63tXkYSepQBCRyJ2b/xcISxoMBEiprpFrksa6paAzRdRkJfu6ZTB7ueaI4iRMh@TtHYvpsZ226WvUQMOwgPMFLWlK/d6PYCHXVlxMTuNEYXuB2w0eYL1caiN2N5Hq5JncF40LZIewyZTc7D8UxNSQ5Hjc5VI62SB4PjUWNaoWWLdj7jpudSCxGCCUhg8Omq5zXPICwt0l3CFLFNYcshXF7Qm@rr0aRvE9bnBF1qhoIOu4JBEGMnpqR/F@urGTqGXP07OiGK8oPJ22oj9RTLMy8sjTSkRNRthofZg6HjmBqiY8cOnIQjqNqRaXhBF7rGQnvFil@ayXuIEaDrTmgvQO2KsP4a9WN16vj9RmxxGvYc4@ifLShZFzGe@SpKsUZyzM2n@fDGO2BF@8jP8SgQsjaZcEbOQiq1cBbo69yS0XWEg3xbW/xsQ3XtBXR8gRl7hqiTflcmy5kVKrwDw1MVtvwnCO1eo0P4TW8bU7DiWTL15knWrX0@658vp876d2e/uYyJnpLNKptRSa3MNjOWHiu0MmbTsVdjlRaYUINn/XiGs74SH5YICQiRbKr2OXt@lyWEzpK4Q/4sKQSJdRkwyX69vizAZx@gmYxjkU06C@6yazo/9SbvKlpb@Rd9KB9c@SUszKGSxfR0zhm1CRT76f56LS4nQfbVau7Fav4FnYQ6/iQz8q@x3maC6wt/QluJAMdZWnrOfotxQ4wQ95OgUaCPE2qnXGsivieBdlLSU6ge5lyPY9mKynjCE5SfqMzhUuHi4to8DSgfceBPK2I5k5djQYnpYIT7Ulg/g8EV6mkEmNdmvUOEI2FlIDYiLELNALK5fOUxDnXNcFliPydP7SB2KwOh7s0mI6tFf9DP6M2a6y0VsImG10zvVe5VbnaMPhiisRG6qDdTS09UfuvNy3/89@GvyXFyazX7aUS/4@SvyfVXSXmkB3p7bt5uklvJTWRbv09Os3QGpseX//hfKr/1I8FBynST/m2tGVjr0@RWpshF7pJb6/SQX12lev/v73@nNizKiQ13sS7W04oRKxiK7DT6zLuUripopRxLl8JphR2zAEMsDOlsTi8wjJqsvsqxmC6prSpufB35ytij6CWeDbPGbCokkgxjT0E7IylQRAUZAWlMKNoqYrthzDbAvCGa6uen3npAJ4CftTmHrdKabjwNYDK0KMci6sCU1EjneXnYyr1JWPOOjYSxKSmYLSSOdnquffW88P8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/1fr5o)

[Sciter](https://sciter.com) is a library for creating GUIs with HTML/CSS/script. There are two variants of Sciter: Sciter.JS (uses JavaScript) and
Sciter.TIS (uses TIScript). TIScript (Terra Informatica Script) is a dialect of JavaScript developed for Sciter. Sciter.TIS executes only scripts with
`type="text/tiscript"`, which naturally separates it from other HTML variants.

Sciter.TIS code:

```html
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
```

Sciter executes scripts after the entire page was loaded.
`self` or `view.root` is the same as [document.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) in HTML5.
`.html` is the same as `.innerHTML`. `<p>` is a workaround for the bug mentioned in the previous answer (Sciter inherited it from HTMLayout).

#### Golf

**CSS:** `@media screen and (min-width:0\0)` → `@media all\0` ([link](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1538))

**JavaScript:**

```js
-   f=[].sort;d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265
+   d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,2][(":"+[].sort).length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-29]
```

```
            (":"+[].sort)  -!!d.head  -!d.fonts  sum  sum-29   #     267-#
            .length                                   (index)        (value)
Opera 9     30              0         -1         29   0        267   0
Chrome      34             -1          0         33   4        257   10
Safari 5    38             -1         -1         36   7        275   -8
Firefox     38             -1          0         37   8        259   8
IE11        40             -1         -1         38   9        262   5
IE6         40              0         -1         39   10       265   2
```

`d.head` separates IE6 and IE11, `d.fonts` separates Safari and Firefox.
Pluses were replaced with minuses where possible to fix DOBELA, `:` fixes DOBELA and Chip.

**[Haskell](https://tio.run/##dVZtb5tIEP7uXzFxIhUasMBxk54JROfEvURNmzff9XQ@117DYlaBXbIsCWli6T7e77w/khuwrTgyRQKzs/PMyzMzi6cki15efKLAg7AVR1ljG8wHCFhGpjGFByI547Os0YV3SR4rFjNOwRdJQrl612hQPxJgcmja7Y9daDogcz6L/NKE6afp0uSr1oFVp2X@@ZXOiGL39JwpKkmcbQLb9cCrnGTsKheK1mA69ZgvZMb8U0x8DbEG@/jLG9gC0yN8dkkURsc3HLWtD3UIxol8/FlCbWu/BtMvFOUBDU5oSJDt6zymNciDGuSvaRozv@LwRNTm1bbq8vqaJyfUZ0ldiLZVBxBfBBeJkGnEsuSaZkoyXzHBN@F2DbwEnwufxEhPUOOyXYO5qVzUJ2V3fgo4IYqsO0BlZM40zSYsrm04pcWnWBC1qtKa4XZdJBf3VKI@Vqh0gXOxkcBeHeyaTjHbcqBuHrkiRX0qnbqOuBSZCllxkWJ8SshNh/t1LP/OmS@CTW9LyF4NZECTNCaK4lzc0jjeBNUS7YuUBoPHlP5BJCsTXAX48uKxJBVSwaWkcR5QZ7n87fS4dXaxWpU1an3KuY@5tY4Fz9SbnQXLK9GAFqp1SiUNhL@SIUZJEbf6hU/Tsg1XG@c4sDmZ0dYyodbg1Hkyx/cP375dDW4Hg7/M@brZm0g8LAJBG5nDMBLCfQplv7IAiOvhGwm0KkYg@kOEccDY89yxmyB16tE04bC6Gg1v7PZ2oNguGl5QNmHP7cEZVw2PuWDak0QEk/aujXrUpVIK2dxGZsMj7uY8IyG9pDIUMjm72IEQ6ASn2o8mf/dLzWMSx09z05PAX2M8yxY8lT7ojEqognsKpUiWG2PXmr/q48yDRkxvqr@RaWvLz1DNxaug5Ee7WiX@lOESrTabcyd0te@6c4cruQNa0OoB6EcdJ9B6MAa9FIZglY827HccPyZZppXWgBiVjzI@orveZyDLwG@7XYxuWftbN80l3YHSoxZCypbUhy4LKj0yd2busJQ9l49Ds9kcmebweQQNz2l4hWs5j9vEzfKpkgSPEWtq4@HrFCjDL4QTwdSdfi8cWfkBJ8Zax5TPVLTwCcTBYiDtaOfHs/bfv//oh@YHdyFzKlvPMVUwbo3dwuHldwz7wt1zhzjQBo6NYeFzD2/bwNPBwIPFwKPYwNPVwI8mvqOWdYDrDt6oY@O@fTDa2tJiDU@qpmEVVss2bGobmjVhwUQ3bjWr263I0w0l@hzriYKyrNin1RJ/ib7bfh9rgQByaFZtO7RHTpUkMSIk0ohKM9eUxAt13YS991q8o1WED/K0Pxx1u/0ivdJBNzXz7mh/98Da/aHrDmhbupvRu4rhhDBeUZBuYZ@5KZZNIXd5MrRgC7PGqTPnWHYUlp/x4RAHA0nB/wKYJHueHTa95ghLNofG/w):**

```hs
-   [246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]
+   206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]
```

```hs
-   data B=B{u::Int};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x;print$ u$[-1]!!0
+   data B=B Int;_=B b;b=x#x;i_= -1`mod`2+1;print$ [b,0,170]!!i_
```

[NegativeLiterals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153744/wait-what-language-is-this/225097#225097).
`b` is for Flaks, `i_` for Prelude, `_` in `i_` for DOBELA.
`data B=B Int` is for StrictData.
`_=B b` is for ExtendedDefaultRules.

Answer (score 4):

## 306. HTML+JavaScript (IE7), 14340 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){d=document;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,window.XMLHttpRequest ?-39:2][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]}</script>
<style>
*+body,text{display:none}*{+color:fff}
a,b{-color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
b{color:000;-top:-90}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[ s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1ute_[2]!!\0/ad4ocod"r"n;z c;op>s0}e}tfeqFloat 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rk@PKdSD4WfD8iCywbpMoEiABvskiu6urq@8tqburVVV9@0osXjZIgiS6SIBNkFVkV1eHpNnVWmPvrEcjO2TZ4ytrxrPyeiLGO7GzlnfsmQj764RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzmZAEEWyeqW7IiNjQUJIJGPkydPnjx58t00vd7PfhbBiz11@7Nu3x2zseWNWXtkX1gjjd2fsXum7WWNtCShr71RdzKwnLFXkiJMZ8wbm6Mx65tOd2J2LRYBW4PNvzt2f2yNEsyzLNa0@u4luKcZc6xLdui07DZAYmP33HLs19YI3DKMPbD6bwZvxqzlDgam0/bYcGQ7Y3LNMvbUhI/OpHXOzKY3Hpmtse064JRj7JnTNwfNtsnI@3Bk8UB5BqBa5xRm0aXA2GN35FkQg9uyPM9FyyJYmiPbfbT35OMl/3qKfWwCUsO@NV2KXtfZc9satZdDGOzT04cPl23T7Cuq67CHN1HSM2xvMnYPx8vws2yvazkmM7SiZiw75oCYY6tfSBVSC07g9tAeQW6aItdK85xxJoOmNQLiiyy8tMc9DQKcupzgzHX6M2ZNARjg2AFv1pjZmFssm0qhT/ifWC3Xac/Bg5UFcACuNRiOZ0xljit4AJzcEfOGZstS21bfHthjq836NmDndgQ2HoMMZ@fW7NIdQcarnBUJEW9oteyOjUFECjwJme2B1Zx0mTsZDyeAnsfatmc2@@CtOWNtq2NO@uMEa4IbEI/sL3uWI1CynS6m4/ncBiE4UAQ49ts60Mbu9xmgc47oYNQe20WHS7RHr02LsLTaCOpgTi6AZPY9P/WLES9Eg@GejtzuyBwAo7YtosGnh0@Z13JH8AU3@uWlYBOYljlmu7ssevDkQZRVAzJqo6YUkLTCrhhjEd@RXZj9ieWxgTmDuJ0xFC7mUv75ISTwzqJb0RKLptPMSLFMhmWgsBWYkU0xKBJFMECpNdI63DlmFFhGB77PRhMYT2dkdu2@xaF03X4HAeWRY40sM@CZykQT3LVFceRZusByeZbPsjw8i6xoQCQIMcP0YhbuHNwAoQgY6HCnMzymgC2QnSAJbJ91zIHdn3HowyGCb7GszvIAEdDUAbJRAAhFAyEsXmF44x4QtmdeAEi1b5@juLACiYG5lYRXcmcnSSILZSOP0utZ/T7GCoQCEmULLA@x5iDRGYgZ6GgUDD/x3R4ln/DKp@AGHPOQ4gKQNwWUSiGp8nDDN4ghA@SNAcLFAHlh6GBvgDmNUMFfDtxykFe5gLRGm2gL0hXC6khMFCg60gCCMci6dIZB5mUge9OYvdk0AzwBgXyOgUwp6KyQYYU8A3IVUwxIrwMymPc6yDIdkNARGGSpDnmqAyI6MIsOQPV0lkkhuuppdIewaQgLJNAzECYDZsgXPYc3hIOM1yFKHeI0jOKctQA3IwuJzKaJ54wcZF4e3IBYBuBqALcYgK1RAHcMWwDCFZAl8z4hzP6wZyItIAeQkYHVgCBZwIlgg38wG/k0Zyny3bTGdku6lqBU8RowLHF86YESAKQJMxlWoMCAc@6JBRJQAYG0KKwmntUHLgIZ0jLBjGwLpR0lhw/HHmsoZ6GastwLrEip@C9E45GIaI6wFgV51bZGI4Z@obL1EiRMvEnTs15NsK6d49UB6WSBYO2Ydj9AgIqOOaZ6AN5RD@KbLaLdGbkDKl8DFBZ91x2uEbsgmi4R0CfupTVHfS65zOGwD/Ic7C0gxMTsAzKXJukDpC6EY@UIQSAM1@rZAJCiArlqj6wW0V4kHUKnQQIvolhiRvVOGqHcD1ULaTZ0Qah6GMaZ9PslqO6sFktXk23rIok2vOpYrDIQB78ygfpQgGiaUJdTZYpYBJDuGBpVU6d@znruYDFpXLwcBknv2VgF9C/NGeReBySLNTUHoHEwrNYdqLgHwDE8BzEnPF7xHLK260THAZTLEVSvkOggJQCyTzQZ2wML9DEXgmCOZwhpFG6EWXMGrEzUymikjnFMlgilScuE4haZkAUvLFCxtSctpBrGbTvEQVAheFRbVQEuVzo1NECRG1lmm3tD7QIxCulHUNtZQHShCrQIEGooluOBtuNpzEa1EBi@63aAx6iKBlUDgs7jaVHaMeWB1VRraRJRGvlmcN5nNmsNhwzsQT8BtB6mClDHui9t9hoc@z2P9VuT0WjGpkPIAHsAvsYtt9MBpn1tDXsAgg3arDVrQamEVCLTSG2XJFBruJTk4GvbAj@OBcnef/o11rWA2lAjdwBT4vR5AoZDSgKRwnR4be2YQClMQms4I7IAmCBEx3U1tG@7lkc8AtpMUOIxMs/qUomA4tWZy6ABah/AnKAROMCyIHBEqUL4GKG0MjEYlcj8jy0HSkwLmBHKOmQf6qN7rAO6f6iyRuXObLWs4Viwh0tSzHZCCs3RQ1RoyFYVwDSvJ23fA11sAQMJvEo@54RqcPOchCsq@qRnmShiRQMD6nTHClRYxgVKf3YjevBxsRS7/AL9LGDwQl6Dw5BKAmp3JBsmY5QgKBTtVg9F4BiFDGkZUMhGk5vJB7tw9KMBUztB3IiNDtJG0pKBFeKxHoYKd/8mIG3YR1jVBQv0umBxC2jTG6yA7AZI9tthWy1paiALbwM6cB13BVQgZgAXvSy6UF4QM56g1DD7ATNScfEW8gjl9Lzti/UXVJ3DoTuCksGFzgwlGc@yEHe5vJ0SC6oIBdrNizUq1BRRrOfHY97mGvahHURFDEsq6JMmSAoQYrwFADLP5TGGEKZST7AEfpck8TkzQRXqOBaqpOZoxoFA8qBWhohmzB6NQAxeYN3Aqx6/DtGIT6EqMNttlKxIDir3y5FryNH7k6Y9XW5mtNBSe@lJF@aIdbCFMQJdAwpRLNrxokqZ7ClkyElOusNxkoLypwweyZMGWR7rQKMFKoKHIGhOZk4rJi8UMTnB5Mm4U5AVMGBArpqxL5vD8TJ2L8EOmWZwDuWavsqsC7W2qsJTRTvCBB2SGjqYI1AvoBCCll0stpsmewPSY8TU6T6FRrWQ3rqWCeKynHYQlyAE4hJOr8aj8EYtMqihWg1TgN4p5VRJLBDwPSlBAWWwSCZF/YkWpORxN1JnuOXEoe4BFuMaiMKuAhUdKoAYIWODzmG37HFDaCl37vj6ylalAswGShSIzbYSVu79fhQNJDV41kgJEZFoY/dkjGUjpkB60fM1xwa0JeDUSpVdjXsjKHH0fS2BJyCr5CAn@4QV@fzEPp@0lzPaQUv0JGOpA13Jbo3lsgSVPy8NlU1UjS5QFZT/KFIVmRfDE@gbzEu2mKGy8DayPNR6KwKVUA7HEAPBqytJxIMKuzlD789afaEScBMUdi6NmoD@uWipB4IoIXQCv9DeKKkcCBYHDoc93Tv9pCLKIndMNm2ntGDRd1tmn6y30bvsh310eP947/hrjRUw@naztGyRtDOFHFa1k6nadSbJjGaUtsMw5oAfNDbDxoCLfmRJODPVnYZUpVkLKpepT86j468skwQ0ISQHxQBmvJdUGu4HlC6paXq9pUqYdeNxiDII4vtl6iHzYQYGRB3dTR@fp5PXrzHzlpEaCnvErD8xOQDfMnno@OE0dFxSwHynZofXiBQWtFDbwf7PuSns08fnY9Sal5EhVTrEMh8fPTw4rhDYnumdW/2@Sl6S3hh0KXPU1oDn@5O2Ja3yA@IPTC0W1@aIoz5NuK4kcKu1QOB53rI18AEANnE0l6n9gZ80rwe47y@njWzVVsAB9E0QlvXKsD7U@lBEQ3hgFdfClu6qWpQc5pVVYLWyxgpcF6utVjZr5TPFcLXVmsfZDgMdkFJsu77eOAKnc09FG22uRQq1WqB/8ugG4h4pkdAUUH3MvD7TKC6vL2HrRbVZ1EvuQwvN7Vvac5J4MpOVZDLqd3xqLY/anCH/B1N7HEsp/K0r4Bdi39s7NB74nkVHHXVgUKMBm@BYM406ONDQ8oBHHLfvdl22A2G4duhHCGrT2mTudV3nRg6ZaIlJjeDIBchf7K8xh1DX2K@p4Uihws1VPuphOt4lSGk9l0YiEYUIVJL8ay/NCxPINU/3yeHXD6AS0bOpVGBO0QUkCIUhcqGpFbIlC6ZCRJrAZ2UCg1GMG6Xdd1BDwwiYaCHogoB7c@eVliQxteRK/ytR@rJ7g@Iv3dkSa4ENZy0whEh2@OTpo8MnB4/3PjsbG9nswncmVcwB4SC@JuhCWo/TDUvrDi@amCwEF4GyMcLiBVJgAg0Uvzt84o1AcGvoReMIrOEaPv4T@7Lbc6KespyYS3RVXzotzkKPsfBxryIgNLTbfWyMjPiwGdbnyD@98XjolZJJKOW9SVODRmvyZcvtm90khYOKod9P6th0OTzCfg1vVQhAxptZPATv0wLVYUYdh2Z/4ELjhYbiUDSwGAdPnVV9u9uDtjCO11kjRQs4mFKTbEMLAdrKySBtJIDpC2gr3n4@yZy1v6QbBc7XesrIJGXf20LxB79bHQuaTjGorYAUytInO7tzdofNQEojpGUgEabtiCEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9GqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDrajjD4yILe9xEkNV37/OzMqYOCfnaHcMOBsNqsXtPrSpndDLIj/Ctl4N6F5CHv@hbAu2QE1qQ3WyPP2uZNcdY2qXS1WXI8GIo6Rx2yx3ugSL12QV63rXDZwwDJsGNyZ8FvEj2/Ta7oEOpjUAkfSKkkFCioaYH1koiXCkovqofAOSC3QgHYvDeDp4MPP4fkCDa6ke9tN@pRXz3qNdhJ6g2BiNTH3EIp7WH/4Bhqx4DzUUpD5qKQZpdWFLvPTY93UkIgMejoh4e2WgCBOuODjmgnGGwFJqBQ1DwHyQF8hb2lvXkvIzb6gdMgQsIJOx9Ag3Bo0KALcgYC84Ts8YTwmMhmMUnnjnvpILSmxQpq0x7zPn53MsLBPLsdTht4TxvcD0CjxIXkOo36Na0W72XlgSkV0Ag02cAauNiVANoViQKLkmDyEUNsC3rYUQ3FKqXiwAnAV9m9fZBiLYv3F6kDbEQBSx2w6HiU3FO/njTV18DNG3QrTPxeeACbMv3UJwD1RAYj2NRLInpASTtxB@TpOfW3oON9X92VhrNxD1IMHCabFXdoOcttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sKrq1tRUtRavRBJjugmkXTXfRFAfTXTKpZEJ/GpooRIJM6FqjEGhXj17XfMhTpY48MEXN4bU9jJm1UildT5g1XbwNfCuQFUB58K3iC@BElUoFjYoiVy9xqAb091Da95F3TlojeyhI8GVQCPi3oEGaiADNe9TmR1YZ26abKTKojKDRaKGKGRtFz2qps/rZ1Vk7fnYdTWBopWxWoH0IwmscG2jdkTsZguJWy5RUkG1KLV2ql5uVaCq6E4sV1D5EZCrKRwUlbnJax6IW8FTs7CwKJBXUqbV6I4I3TRiKEhAK8OjY0Mro92NR7aoA8TeVuhKPQlglmgCxXIlGgS4tJIJHicYeAc5ED@0pkBIKJlRx4TEFEpA0JoXF9evWsDcbhT0EvW6gZWMP@nwwHgoDSfGwlHzNw4cVuoWWvq/3cn@g3GLnHepLwxmX7hLH9Cy5MDHEr3cv1M7AHZvJTzVoNGmh6jK6FU2qKtSE5MIhUbIf2x4WYdOx3IkX7mlc2QGKsYPtaW8CwtKfNZMArrKHktXquSy6fQ@gs2CYB6sSHLFS@biXD6Dd0uBGIYpaCQ6WgHZB00lskIs41YT3yuiEBBc9ft98Njd8pQWxlSkMS2FEdtdxR5YKJIEQEk3@oKlCUpWJGSWH1PN1Y1xCuFKVhg1v2wKJ@LDvmkRbLq5D40HDQSg8tM8hyLHVlvogPzogHjWeFyOrndyRaHDWHfWghoDUoCQ2gtwaCIek6w3b2ngKQaUYVrhhR966A6XzkrUNw8i1sp2S74ZcAcTuQSZhq9SBJq7vpOrgqIhMPuDdQn4b/cnRgwPed0KVLVav2I/WGLjtCeiVot10bDndBDsAfrIdd2ADGfzwr8/7x6475q18@FjXM8MbzfZg0jepz2e5W2ZjuJbbdPvUFbQp6Nz/ZOSZfZN3Qvmue58@Bl3/2elJRSuFPCXNi8HGuLEfcnW0nJ6H4TFHGmb1h4c8zpjydlbGesufjIZiRjjk0GEipqJBHvn2ebT3ixSOoQj7AtoPcBoa6MqiF4E@A0vhsUgecWoazugRlld66hrt17bBAn86@eOK4xzbK90g@4txp7NgnSbrcxVFU39unSFrPkVtoY0YRinLPeF8tQU/YUA58hNMW1v2J4RXMMWgZ/X9EcRjUExwlAzq9j6qT9A2QU2czx2zQJEe4mAISWgcYmMt0DW9G90WUKaGKvctRbaonEAdlkTNRdpOMtHFXaaS4rhiaNLj0tOFpj31nuxW@YA1Np1GvNWW5J3v2w0AsVst@7OJ1nnDmKLRwBtBJdwgBCWThu1vJDWYhOFRn7pEQcqSl4RWw9RIqWfT/EE96REROkw@O5t@lDI@g8YHzvnavpPsWmWMbi216Jv3Q7d6IDZYfLpIMsiHidNx@22VD3pB/jPeXMKMEFMNgllnJPDBxh75E85snMQiJgaCuAzNVbsBdynrqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyxN@eJizesBjXYheYN@/a4zq61sdvoYeLHk5GzPA@Oq5SjkTnzJDFTpcL2jj/@tJaqcwjSwMSBrALPrak/jRL0YNB7cLYqmHC@zdgeU8VOEwtsTK@uAVJTGvMA9AEGj6DMgohEihD1N9abeVo6FjQ8YxZi7s0GCWYp11qnb47HlsN5i48mric3H/YR0VQo@rtiDKHEUjTQAoqmjW6AYpmdnD44OD7WgEO9WPQAB2RKUOzMVg/0jXWJ9ikZTnyJfdSOso8wjIKtcAmKFDQmGiI8MG8ZmBuaExA7ioKuNYqBpYJjKS2wpuErCsgVLkEgnDXVGhONAmAxS4E0EbDSSvyfObzlJPAssSiLEyWB3LE7JaCtrWgTx36leVBvkBoKXqK87UlTZCvbMRJf27pC/DOyBzgWDE0m0gIhDbUa2wLpRr5lVnnLPq@l1GI9vs3q9TIf4YeAqNPTlFsxfdMU9OTDYSQgBc6HolXWWZrE68dAPbcYiuOnA89Kgm8B2dGkObtZSuVtQ1YCZNXXYMEd5WUkV0wy5Sj6U5tIhNBMqMUZTYvzpULJekaN7KXJ4ZAcH4EgPTgMGeOpZFsVpiuKjxkH9NwcYdO5xJ66nmc3@zR7tdO3@UywoLIuCcIISD5lwtGVsWAQ3bA8QznDzJhPWeYTgQUlyJ0qGmhJYcrIIqawKyQmkdJAKrI3b9BCZtsGIzaQccYwp@@136YF@fjIBWQfiRnQYZ2DhIaYnoKi40yS/cbb4vgvuvCGQfJiSedVL@RwOK5z2s65S6NIgamR0vQs6plB6MF5/2bIju316LHgNcCB@zXWYecNmh16rPBAgylimJ4sqJteaNiQnWbymF7UY78i5sWpKQvRNq3OxOnSmCaamfrqFp9qsUCeO82mvc4rEAFnm/nvFd5AVmLJM7SMpvulBzt4oFoE@cnbRPOkL89qYgt0h0pqDKHE@79@ow30v5k7PaivsD8zMDRAU8CcUjtrM0sExQ96rM5Y3u0@6dsmEYZMt4FsmSNIktkPDKtB09C@qoK@McCBCpHjwJv4AF10A5txzPk4o/9eHcmqoToH5HZrnd@lWV48KhpUguZim4jAdS7bokAkZHkmWFM@sBNquKPAvR0pfyoWI2bm@d6bjCf8CerwrZloD/HeVDaFz1TWbOoWNEjNpm1tyPKReT5pu@rwvBuoxbkVfuepp5FlFbQSMcjcQOPq5PMEjuwuVPf@e523ef2avKTXbVzhORNvqDapbd/mX1QQBhtiGPX5c50XW6xUCgzrqWb36fGenCigA6OIORZJnMGqhohmL5G5bzZnqAr1PpzLgvkKIHEqrXg8lV4zYD0crg@P7VMKXyyuDj3VWpweq3oeknyWrMr75ijBYt7sLbkK1ZU9MPuq0Q4Z1wrzVdMdbngNRkopjHWB40QXK3NuTn2skFqTvjmamzaw@BwPf3BiXT@3qDZEWW65fdvDAt1fJzX9OXfzuHCeMj1C8yrsVZRsQ0MU63E1MK2WAm5rjHNR17DVe8g0PgcUZ9qG@ERz1xGr5V7ivVaD6EFjmD9XV2qvV2L1HvJJ7bf6JlTla2uEhV5H7NW8hVcvbc@ix2rCnq9EdNzqr7RfLAV@f2K4f/A2zvbsvuuxE3puIlB3BFTgz9U8HaalbToq9bKHzRvEkD95Yp6hZr/r9nOFbtKEx9pcn4w6KPrF@32FXCCkdP0WIeVrQK6ji/da0X6eHJ3flkG0/muEE2dDxg217CpJJQZ11qcO2gY4Irg6ZQ9TBQqpJXkf4pqIcSzn0pz575@j9lhHWr/2GM5IowYFDwMUC2AYj7iW/fPEltkcW/v9hNINsPnbEhHK3PO@BfUVPW9kKTNS@geG0FOp9xdRnf7Emlgr2xpHzZcWLiPe0M54f6RSIhnbYggARx1wzUvg67VoHL4X1lhV49dGYWJCq926XZtZFGpDUMCH2Hp@CoanaLgZoutMhgu5utBAc443k6w39Iu0217ADl0@VA4VblGWFlR0z6J7Y6OJN/Jw5lklk0qlhA4TGspZ@NjUmEoHYV/a/LkQMdnMY577xeG7Uci4Og4iS3hu41oRZKxr25PnYjHp2I41nuHzPaVp03X7H5JTIFTbNmpjoFzSHN5NOXZD3RGrU9i898LDPo9mZ12/Ba9tRPMS6IPt5k2ZHh5req/cVHE0dYAjXYufm3twQiNXt8WCy7mxW4jP6u2v1yVFh4iuFbT8xlLHNVS3afVN/prmMpvgFbX0RniLQkOMAuOoMR8rno/xR5aE0nAGxLLb0FDpWQOLPjco@mb75cTzX2s9TV281zlPLauVnB5YrXUehjbIBQefC4PTIWVp7DrQxBrjBEJsqvRxiqqwXSeB/eHElUQ@HJhdi@9RsUlSzvsscJoOb9nNjat7L0p8ak4Lgs17mNezBBSqc2vm@e@VAB/PWpCvk8HtPW5Lhb@F3aDvUdrXzY29WcU6Pbfn9Kwen5AefK0rHMCPY76nyCbUAetuD@fIDYcLc@fD9Oy7/f770BNFIxeUrttZidMBrqrFJWEfBHdmNsFBvG7tvzPHXHagYW2p6VkTqJc8d@wOLZW@1nntY18Pf66Tof7o98/bibSxqQ8U8d8/L/xb25Zd0x0Ph/RqDPsTjx4UVKXF0LfpTR0@54VmW7qjrvbaHTQ1YamJCTE06L5axDTtcauHi9A5Z1tdt9nq2bch3bTMsWOfJ/1eH/75Xm1XpIzN1AdorfVtIO9opiG/VMLuJ/g6XJfpogOJV2uBYYO@sqqTjtZ7q0PzvOXxDlE0sRL2CYdKI18VXqLl9KVXE3s8BxqaJBX08PKRCTSsw11My1irWdHii7kYFtM11nIpKemokKtWChQefW3/0sIEulARS6f5Yx1C4VQSRqEJLx9CbjGpiDoI7VDXLdgv8NfCbKiVlZzTm3S9mwKT99i3QUXDx/puC5okHeq1hjrLdMRrHZmNfhJXT8K7ATrXxNo4rJLdOK5C/vS@aro2vBrwgqybrO1D69tDjz@Z2lk7GicmSUFbfHnIkNNmtroxLTKmbXX4KAiablMRBy6N04IOorZwTB870VGYc8WLCy7H7YJQV/ts7tn3u05tWTn/aHX2B3Wm@tkTq2viJO5H9hhnga7gCmLZVfOWboX91Ynp2V@dQMrWMRtuBcFHIkfhPQPwawW8x2bXbn2ykBEBkoLAYgopfy2wP1rdzIvLnu3hHKrAsKFjClmOMzFyXQPaDSt8LnfdB7tgzAsQX1@50veq7nV3OMNlaDMybepZt8fUyyre65qO62aXbUTicjIYTjzxWo0DzdIK90IPzsneu7QBuPoKRCvrmf3x6p7qUJcraGGiUpwb12njX7f7bpd9vZBioLSBEobK@QrGuQ/V81OcGjRyVnAixf2eI5/Y0aGOeMJeQd5aaabajj3e3JszHuM0If@NieE1By59SD7Cp3bvQyGop6sp8uh2XX@@5vmW@h0478SdjFoWGoONTMLNAhGrte9Pa8alIi5uxHIZbqVtHL2B6tB1JmN1NHE21gq5jbVCiU0LuRAbsNhXDx4/U8LcQNPAb9NCLWj8Tbz@bG5aO2dgiclsBxSx9XJ00bfflnjA9106pjnIt4TZw82hWiSuH7ir2jtPZyNr/N4NJhD@k8EDq4Ujh7fG/cR97Dou1EZDEJSDY4tvJrAw12N1QAz2CJfLA33at0ZzQmDXVEJc2zCHVhPytz83vU9dxAE/MMfmmqqI@gap/ReYbuUVu9@0Ri@p0y9kXtekXUToE2tKbYv1DMPLoDputbhKjP1xC2VkYcTGG7quw58kbVPw0h9vlipQFdDj/cfKNZzhv9AvsLJ9tpjUows@UcRq890u1qV1ZDXdPn9umJbk2HxagDmyLS/5CDdPILtchqmgfXkbZUh@owyZN41Ak70wPRqnX93UmIPUpx8wC6hnjloujoQJw4YJOqEdD24R08GiAT53oAmEn4LEMlsTsffibWj1B80BPdY2GEK5eWw1cblRk7YJGZvTm5nJe4bEHgmhSV3BzgK@uMJCnWOxp9AaUW6vthbaUYtUtYf0IEm9dric5uuojm21XpvYa@YSveZ90wvukObkEzKu6asOFSPqRU6atIR@ZUlanL0GCk3fUse9EbT5k@NN3dv@/i0rxkMmAwsHmRdHYdaqrq7Xo8S6q8fTA@E6slSxdyDIkmAfQa4fqntrNU8ED/@j@19OQiXcyGX8PU1AdN0@gg/IT0aOeL0PBz51vXHHnh4B3rjuYJ04wWRlIQi8eMlA0866REDuOZM@733ohqZeDdrUHFNp/1pV7ZO4Hluq5VyotMPc9GaKXL6aLLmHm6GOrbYqNljAkQb1kb@wLPAm3isGUMOyEed76klO2GkuI2aAriLupS8ZQN9yx@rQo3dy6D09fHR0qg09fWX9tNfD9Rg39LiFHRuMQirUJfXSHIXGO/mMtLbtjZP3T3R1/9Ghhh7W0JuPaKjwwpG5hdfafk@x9aiZNNe2gtDVGq9WED85ffwoPl/7yWL7vZE7sJSw8/7JSQLXtnz5ZKVzOPRDKB0dd7o2@OGBrisr2PeZQ6OD66TnipjWQTq1oDUKzPgJ3/DlVuWq5Q6t9ulsaH0KlSdKcO89o8@tTeQT88LuYilkxbWEooLKilouo4QmZ0Nj2xoF73X5eW4PUVq26JXkr7XTUVBzSCdH6dXaw6YR/2UthqXETIQPC6SnbnLr2FahZHR7aEqa3i@KmK7r6@h8YnYgX1l2bWYtelg1Ptx3L95jKNkSjRc1sFLHwFWqfetU8rw6ANGdxAd2zwtLMDbXToPZBCCwzq0s8JeWMzMdlcayNqkXJQiNk9o2evm69R4DUsEMnwvcEHrlGF8wq57FWmRUbon4dBQKsr9///C2AMeClpt9ffzkGXtqeri7yWaPYYyt98B4rhm9VLHfCrfWWzuc2h4BKGMjvO5wdXkusRNz1Had2fT2QTha3IpVO21WHMDCL/Jk9e2pvaquavF@raerpxndFjdfx@HOFvTg8K43AtC7b/8LXU@laE8jfOsp/nlLzvgFnMXQZM5wo7yw0@lhIBpaqLdoYKGsbI0@sqY4HYX3Bq9q1K@s33Ib6r68sr464W58zc/xxAnvQuslxD4CfKkeXzzlaf5WwbGYE48ryuJu9OGlYnyRFO5Vxtc3gd83b9iWWMYEDsHKLrF4Crc0Ap3KwiWHEoHANW0xp1LRs0V2F/eEL4HEVChGsCrxnWP8yGps@0osSiqV9GtcmCWXZCYWjQUbQfLNDAEwbsMGiWLquc62x@Cy7S9pYrQdN3vDSA0Dua9nU/ClJcNrTMtirRfgtH319PDpwcnp3umzk1qqfi0rYkUjx81xIDZ/retH6bYMiRd0g@zlW5vSmsg@REdbhaP65vnpYpCypaRVFpI2T5R8F8NsXzlOMklL@5LqNeCnyjw2cgVZjVYctp9iyiCxMrPEV8T1iaTyNgctU5yQaSWWWhXx0PQ8SJZwXz6sgFxZOo2uPGKxGyUUqq7rtkWMnsVuv/wYH@4dPnp2fMB8BOdcc2m3x71KMcs3K0URqFqQTx2bZglUWFQEiUJeVSrRh1EgTFSLshItqKSNQoHRwZtPHVyKKULvsNg2wQcKRoNMSf7XbySvoxpOeFPAb9RHKsoE5dEDO8VFUn/@4zbfSNvfGsE/kWM0oPJOS9AlsQByzfJHpCiVzOH6czlo42pa6RjsmD0/60SifdSBKy9pV6OlHW8U2oSCH7IiNiTyIyIG8TffxZ4T3FwImn0XNi5z5Dh0cK@fRVbGwVba30pje3joCPA8M2kzd0B94oz5fhpi9X0E@EgLJEqCbROyfOt3OeQxursFrNy0urbDPAfUUWtcYi@Bz7B3osTX2qpqNXojiA@anzaj9saDfsjjjc2BvOTZOPnu176T7JYZmKep@/D1K@KrA@Zf5ebPk5jXNzcQmscfRgI3/RJY88gDmiO9Q@erOHxN85xYuM@RLyqZPYCsuSBKo3ceA3@qIGHncGK1TyGjgMUgl8RaZh6fNarHcNexUjKJbIQjPRrN37SmfDLF0u5juWwuoycBSfXCB0jbBXdxoRgHqCglYHzpwh5WXjSBvXZ3mYzajVXJlXluJredz9PyiwDRbfArXfYQuRqDMBBkHgLcqiIY1CdxXcGgKI@iehRFUduFiobcsULCb0cQQmYxIBankYX7z07xoJ3xaObvotfEw2tCW8lvC0CqDtUMmRRZEstvn7hjYJmFhcd8@S1OJuKVGm5P5fGDpGjzOuRB7WZpmq8a8/esF@VLw3LPQaVTy/VjOG/l5wjiBEGU5FUsW/ucnY3PnHqS8yYDNv2hYNkwMztg/mfJ7hqe5eneu7l1WWx54zEkFrt34rioxj2ExLCYkTTSST2nzJOUyaxMkkiRiAaSgxsqvIHoQDSBmGhZ9kt36O3tHxx@@ejpyY3tuchndNkbSPLqbvxM1RK1emCIhpO1mCX3HyZPHt9/6GfEHOlcSAKD@iJSom9Kybx1hiDns32Xk7YKw@XUrcf4OV8SuIxv2tiEGgW6gYee@oB4acad@pDmzS9HbhRWUSub3YTSHF4yBHqfL3q6gWpMubqu1XerZ04kepMTVhSEzyPaDhYCMJ15O9tJZPabicOEBQe@neJRNV64LKZXl0V5O427xOCyy7F7Pt8fR1iEHELp9aMBESlpSd/r2tJ3xNXu@S5OBj@Qju8nE95FI4RwLrWJ4iFQp/7ZdihF5nvQie3XetBG6ttNyd@9hG/D5u8WFezAxnceiSmS2MmcRxwTp91NS1ONhtdjCko7gpVgm3Z08@EpEhRo1NeeTqCt9tQd8p1taRjlgeWbjl0Qvw8mfDzWYl@eDMBfh17HFnVpgeRWITBQMhqgyvUnkBJiQ7dpHLfMg/hquK2bSLg2aGdjU0XrWdO23QXZHlMSINE@0vU6CzZ9w0TTJm9OVKY8m@fCxqL4MS5lC5P9g3b@m84RMGumZjttaxqLXkaVUh3iR/vo5fOLqCKv4iXagVBsydde3oowQD@vb5Yk5liUTn@fv1XSoli8KSXAbhkw30PHP1ajWNR6nkSnI1VQFz8Zjx6BEdSIWGdgDlls4vB9hjRGn7GzmJOgjVnUKt@qzGHxODWR4EUOGqOQHTLx@jtmOjMWS1aACdDWc9r4em0PWU3XtDqYKRKFbeNxN/ugceGeHYoEzVoIUiKwFWQhaDgARryQaJzBIQy6S7iVyoh2a1rhTKd/UMvfRZpQqln1DgudWrSoOcrFYklk6KJULDLgvpviUEsC2BtyztflgbpiTwCgGTRoNSkyF@Q3JV6E4o1wRD4RmwkAOpHQ9oL@HgMMYM03/2v1RnjHDhwoK7gtSunZ6cNGQUnKLNiUoDuy29gzxXfIDRpt4kwDKKbJBa/RMm@jfYzBcLepBt/1ADdDekgFRl4SqZEwGZbP8Jzzpq5v5HoRUOQC@MxgBSBWbjR8cLitmj9GuMJttbD/2c/wlFA5tn03l270L@LRbKoMD72cZVn20faZqm7XjGyqcm@7bprjM5mZyczOgwur12kedpNnsszSLJNM7hi5V@dDPbfzeU17Na3LtUIlcV5/es6ePv3sbeOtIk8vZvJZjOUjbP/ojaxDAiKlPCsyvFdedHzfymtDK12OAtyzMzz9U87LyWQtWoc/Ob2Ai3uqVbWqdrf@9q1Sy0OaprOzCB6qx47uLQKLGYZyYtt2kp0NvXYbbrfH6vxY2Ai/4vGYyoSFWuN2bDDtkN10z@p2JwfmjNvbkQm@Ho5F2Mdff/78ORqe08VeH4vwHDrz4yg1zGyEGSnjz3@ydZ24etrY/fNvDpLWFr6O8PWd68doPtGzH21tfXT/fiaTACpx89OvP/3a3t5e5kEi@7SWvZtRU1u7f/anW1uGsWskt@qep9ejtfPzz2QjlZG1P/9RtPH06Vc9D7MFrzTTwYjPAtw66lTn7DVc5x2GfzK/bofMJpqbndfMiLyOAFtHZvRrRBgvhRXSksLXFtOrd/P/7XtHryLjSNVIPh/Bexx5FckVItwIBvhK@18XkWpkF73lriOzZKVSAWP@v/17CF/9MsBBl9kuPKpZH1ZuFqmqFQryJlLNgUE3DIj3//rGN27p9rnHanDJmbwh363DtUPXroRbQampZHLJu164o99hzBn3xpaLL5u/HHgxs@xAq/u4Fo/H65oKl9agQEldN86owybMWtTfEgmsy4zbsJDdnE@EDbg9jxBPAVMRX3GzsCBW4xbPl/09X3GVn/9jX8dSJLd1z3pQrYIoNKrGTjVO19ZZqcTJn2T5guy697BHK3omR9kL9kgQuyqnCoacSCTuNfDMZTZFmqrTyJyAjNOIRRYoG2HzLxa2ijA/GJv7@VB/B3j9xf/2F9//i@/R7/t0/yfcNctp253kDkf@osovVq3K1ZF8dUYf91iqVCgVkg12fRbbqVXrx0xPffwmmk1HTzCN5ImdKX4PZyS4qlV8@GjgVzXCbarcNLcTLtXgg3zMg6z2x4Rk8okagSpYTC5Saxd1jhvHL3xN8WK1e5BNspEvyvWqkTWOIOt0mTKuyHrbHnMjIkV34dqCH/3huoudx8IGn1tkyV3I64prK0Dl9msBVylSqyXrVh0UWVb1gdzbKm0VSrmSAZmyHnB5HejIRViaaHmtoBkgPt7Wttgx5/U6i/vXWfzW65mmNYSRDC7equpOI1LkH@GqSixyBVf97U7tLbCuiLomyml8V61X4wIjeGmNe/W4en1d0z6Pl8viv1sNjGW6uAkSUr9W1d3PAVbtJlQOlJ5a4/NdABvfre1W3H26tQaSWK1/Xq3tLoYVwe/di6OMvQcAqtt1Fs240Zx7jynx@LaqbtXWpgEA12MMWgWQgde719Xr2u719e4u/HfpeS3eYHu9e@NPr/m1xs/cnYrNWS1ZPUueCbapw7eWrKKNljwDQxXe4A@qISmiQoGSIjtsJzJkej4NJmaV9B0jncxOP8odgGpUq6vYgqmoNT2XratcUr3QWEnlW23rhZyioShquJ0Gro7T2Asp8uLdF/8L3mfvvvgDrPehWBalSHIHmwdF3kqAx2OHPX78GO/HjgN/uB/zy0EbtHiMdg5/ONyH7yew5jZYHEAoMNko5ORGXJ8ZLLIr5/IoFn7pxhWNRv/JC6OYj/IWNK4ie@GB5S@tuv7JL627pMibIpbzlsd4mqQIlXvICyg/VTRe4aP5Cn@PXuPv1Rh/py38Hb/CHzt9jb/jMf4eN/H31MPf6Sv87TXxdzrA3/1X@Hs8xt@zLv6kSAWU7e27qX6qldLP9XMw2Cw1Yqleqqe3sSWQslhqlpqx1MDV22Cy4JcCk53qsFSXpZyUo@vgCIYxS43R1IFXF34dgDKCn43jyOd6qsUglj4A5afl0PsNCDLlTKpBE1J@YYFarOlaSsvZddxjvCbXjWKBaUhhrVF7cRat4@aVRjHDmjNr6@wFi3igUpcjybOzJO8cYEamjNuRX183GgdPHjQaSRRFZ4/do/n/6GgQ/tz4Hxy5j4/cgQv/o6Ojx8yqxu/F1XtwVarxXfG6G6mW756VVCy3vqiIJHfvnlXTKppzcSj9BtrFP/CaQ4R3detMijLQVC7LpA@VLy/Kl2UyBJ9gaJQDD8IbN4BlWehRYFP2FapLuC4uyRIfaLx8fhaYuCH5/PIM2wXQ4Av@oHCGP/8B/vb/u/6Pn7FYrQ76TezqejdGl4I/Rbm6vroWz6oSi4mP2C780AK@McjVdRWN5OkKTLWYUleur7kdPGPKLgdYxTh2qxR47hEKfySIk@Llj9g/7BvjFtcZbnNtzkfqz86mqZRSbvrb6uIolfmGBkyVMh2Sst2s6fU/@xFtnnxXIU/ZTLms7zD@YWSMcjnjf@UL5XLB/9iOxYo3r2rqrp4DBSeTUZRyGT7u@mBT8BmALQBY/yMLUC3PbFG5L0euDo9oW2EQE9mIginigiGWot3H8SCLqFyS79yJiQMy7@4pd@4YxdSbN4HNcAhW@oJVo9G2R40G2qffvJEbMo2cF7PwnSq8eQOyLKq4o9gTPP8EIoqpOvvIqFKcRXcEhMiDM9OTxhyLnumZ4/Eo9toeJmScEePJCh1PkEq5o7PoT7/7zW@eRSsVWZXJNqMjAIyFZXd3c5lqNZcBc64AlJK3r/hJHd14UVeut5MypwaTt6MR4aQX8gqXjVF0hxqO3a1CAffwYlfXEcp2lskqMZCuCiha1xH8cWu9WOT2LJOLFeJF8atsKawKOgD/Yfs0Hc/s5Hfu1Rn9pqsuFMnlK6uiX1eurBJ2812XW@LwOVxCZ925ky4CTQup8pnUaDzYO91rNCqyLGN1CA@0JOEu4Zk3w1G0RhmeLdZrmL76WTRaKt8j5tALWRaJloU/NQq1BCsUiQyS3cH1sZB2SReN/y3JoDc@JNEXtAWWeD48m99PH@3tH5wmjF1QaYyHe/sJ4@TZ/YiOn9n5Nzmn8fv4YO/B0TMI8PTRwd7JwceHnx48ewr2HrucX74EFs/5O2xa8X3JnksvR69NyzKtiWU1LieTy1fspW03bCBsf2LbttsdMc9qWJY1BG/@VYa7ZXvmy5fmaEgXe/fDb7/74X/37ne/@@53v/3ud7//0y@@/224fwz3d/n7u/@umMXnT7/4F7/37nd@Fyz/E9x/DPdPfvrFb36D3/T9J3D/l5Ddn4g75I/fEsD6lZ9@8b0f/fSLX/0B3P9K3D@4ef/aT1bf3//W@hvDfe/3Nvv57r@H@/c5LN/vd3@H2@H7hv/f4f5@9QfvfuM/8P@fiR8af/fdb/wJPsTHP//Bn/2Xd9/8j4ZR@LN/@@5b33v3rW@@@9Z33n3rnxrvfvPf6qnw4/feff8P//qPfv@v/@h/ov@P6fn77/N/94N//pf/61/@73/5R@L@Cdz/AUw/@cv/CAz7d3/4Q/x/7w//7o9/iP//@V//3R/@@t/9yr8hw29xw//9r/4df/7Nr/3nv/3t7/z1T77xt7/@k7/9rT/86//jV//P3/zPf/Pf/8Hf/I/fRMvf@slf//Gv/NU3v/1X3/qXf/XNL9Y8v73x@cV72H/xj2Dz/ni@D5z3SdeH2nzxc@Hzi1BjHgvwCXD3P3v3m78MDP4bjL379o9xIijca/4/NnTy82P@9f8Bg3EzzeiSAhPcv/7u299FEv0PQCL4B/T6TvCx4MI/vjP/ALL@9lKgiFVarDwLRiG@Ay2MnWJRVKCB8y6F/OkX//JHQRS/vAh1wQ1i/A5KqgW376CMe/fDb7z70T9998PfevfDX8HaTM0UE3sJVd/c@QxVoJp9D3/oMfc@/sDjZ59B/NM4dZWqcfxinwnHzz77TJq@SeLM43tvwPYzsuIX407gxoST7ybscaZq2A83pnzjNlq/CUeNZIhjtHFSBXZ8PSWbZtO433mIPXG8ExE9TXd4fyI@yRadpxI@5v@5cSqxOPrhFx7W4hvJIMKJKLhRykI08ek01HtJ6gdhyG1oFInizRQZpmA6jU@hRQoGiCEOTvfjrFKpxDFgheMDnxy1aoERKvF4BdKNoXmYRKOAIKb3CQqErMSPWWOnMuUB4wiv6pMjLqHVsawbcrxQeQARVqYPGMJC4AT2xYtKtVCZVhHcW06P@DR@n3BCYJX4tPoWvisEM46dSg/eAiqFSjxeLWCEmEiePYkGz6QsJY7SHmdxkQfwph7ae4x9JOsFmY9obCHBuG98xue@79IY211wP4vviOTQ3zfSvUME36KoRCyMu98lVfEu1x7RA8BVVU3TGNyqitjcA@cpBxWnaOEV5xDixBHEAYEFsCHmRZzyN04fEH@ksvPBV7wq8dRsb29Lkaqclo9ohCcOrfbReYmftvGGN41KTM4VZbS2aOY3T521/ZS6HXYe7MBTh//BFk3IjrMyobUdxc69KOPxsY/i/L53b4d9BKmn99xOYmo87Wawcx0TuhuPywbEWnXj0ucg3SRgXwL0RtKmFRpXikuJBGNaJYJu7OjoSKBGFp9XpDhwv5HW8RsHAiaTSQRCaFpCSyTEW6M3WWjCoJGreGvbSHPqjGSGkSlD@6bM0IqFmyM6tFvR8u3bt5BZNCmjdAgtSibmZxiZAjmCBV@Q2e/P/IUDRqYo8eY003P8POwYHZenMEViMbajSHz6LkciGO6NGoVCFE0K5IkW2/Gn6@R0ye8jpC7CIARv4xWyiu@4f8T2jx4/PnhyOqzXmWTROYZWYzhyW5bnbRLMMQy39@QBn91vFHOIRqRWw5hPSwaKJemglCKhefjg@PCkxDhNRA7FAkhKmfp/BSmKuhQZDp/vRsSUBhkP1nDlE3yW5umPGcU0RlgtS5GWhc0SYDj8s7L02Oved6fQlk/IckLPYRNNoR5UJn3NLZUqb/VMXoI3fU8YbgHF14tC6cQ54NruLhFNql6p1OuNRsjgnFStirlBTJeqJwenEOD0iOlGSmPQ0r/K5I1MNpM10rlcNm/omVwxk8sW0lDX5FJZw9CLmUyxUMxfS9XP2FRDXFUw9yt9y@mOe9s4I0c@S8khemzXUgn8Gek0PAFiQs/m61tb/SsVETwjtrjCqVXX8HmlIgW@BBeTviSxL4EVXBAHzpdiYrLa4VFZzBjCnRlifNqQrGehcCvSGTASBycNw1cZH1CCoL0fuqXI1te/PmbVKrSz1cOHUgQEVY/5E2dUu631NGKl9mRkkWuXsbb9qY0nrmht2xv2zRkUz5QmRa6vrzsA6fAhjqrSJw/Rxud1i2yaYL6emtL/f/3i1@6wCoy5mxxWpV0TjJndpAnGJhizu8kmGPk@RgyXSVbksTXFbdO4nVz1rH5HwwUBFZkAGfKu2BewKsJVcWWFa7YruJYOZ8THlKt2pe226Eincltruu2Z5o1nID8FJ1Sizb7bOo/6jjaelIlrsSpGLq@KkqDzl1pIFBLZxKXttN1L7bPHjz4Zj4fHFk2/Z3fVdLFk1Gs1WY7X6trQHdbx4DdezNStLeBLy2yr8O64zthTjUL9OsAfEo5IVaWdOGKRwJRfCQxLjutY1ztX8Zbbd0elTqdzLZmJ5pXKv0F9LA9dj3YfLplNqBtAmJbH7rCUupaaV3NPKtqpRbAtmR2oDK5afNZcSTayBblcK8@/8zm5XL@W7g2stm3iFPqz1NWNQLmUfB34OUuhtxWecugJ0smTB9nOt2aq0lyvGkin@gFUOrX6rr9pE6gHkmGoRlpN66qexv8tBgP/7@/fgL@BTwiVNqRTXLj4BIQUSGGHPcI9oscuO3VdOg7svtVa42O/Z9Kktv2R63m/gJ/7pnPOnR7YfLegwOkTE88B8Ab2uLfGx7PhANc8WqN/NAgHgyYgiMWHe7gPj1HfdVd5yLNnT9ek8nGwPx8Qg2/QB96PDz/@5DT0Pj3Y2/9EyrH7R08eLL2ywlOWPTp4eBp85rmrHzQbgPjawaNHy5/iFcH6Gvtdt1g27xt0CWfF3oHWyh1hzObmxhQan/MFW7YXzNLkK/NK0qm/istkWKCbFmvxZajYfKItIoQWpeeLkjRkjnvJ8inWdvt9E49C7GyBZc/E1SkW6gV9OrETo750R/32pd22tqTHuBCmqON5b4iE9AkAGUxatB7bHku44VAbDynEfv4mnrM@wYNA11jCC63QOLK7PZC4l67vQWqaJoP7Qy8Ib4Wv8WaLMY@D7G649G96lyISqn/m2IwUynfu6E9HwNnVQqpU6lrQQAAZWD2YAnexCXsG/G6OUJJuJ9l2Vs615IdMa0TMHVC5unaNefXhMStg73PLTGd2QAPWUYUAtc@08hGUvqD0oFJaM0DxOUslzXbGBRVFHslO@TVrld1h1UtdW9fjjvWK9qcC3a1c@pvf/jEy9k4SZFhEl2WctLulSxopmUaxkC0U0wZUIsVCJqvnstmEbiRAh88XsYrRC3qukC3qiUKmmM6A1gau2WJeivAZUckdAgnvEoB1Wnhu2S7pqVqvKkX4aBB7HTMVFjGD7wmTLQgj40nVUEnhqsAduyIbGaanGDRRAKLJWizy8OF@6uFDWb6PHzgGvp@S5TZ@ZAupVP6@LFvksl/Aeld2eZgCbv8gj/lHKnV/X5YnHADunCjLPfw4yGEPhyzb@LG/9/AhxtPBDwPDg7dz7sI/@v5HHrw5@JFOUxeJLL8KwIG/PR5RhjA9wA@ME10ecpd9cJPlj318UimAcMz9cQif@Gnd25PlQ/6xt4cu@5TwLEf1K/ixR5csA8NgoZHlLhi6IyiustwEIxYdWW6BqTUzwQ5PicPt9ZyxKcszTiAkkSxPybfZOpflhm@P0XzyySdmb9y2uvyajfi7BaiBiz2dHDxsfvxxs9ttjmZ7Bx8fo8v@/idmZzYZNbtNEazZgMuFMOByPpgtX4DjYaNh9le6fAVcnCWXxqxhIW4N8xXgJK4uRjJo7IPLPrisGkjj0OAagNcmXvcH8L5vNsnFv8iF3tNmUy4jo6LqR0e9QpmhU1cTA7M1csv4Pa1sMRaNRROzWi5VL5MDG4CSlypf0xmvMXya2KRWrma1aSVVr0wreYPPwOjE5LOpkbXlxNbgrl7MlrbMu7qRiU9LuDbY7URZVNXvsph@Z@c1iz1R7hrpTEk@u3tXlWt6/a6hF0q5/Oc7E1lWSvi8m86XwGMqCg1OfCi1fP1uPhsKks/HzaRRyueV8jWQYwxVaxOlSiMWu7TMc0VBdLFhBEngJ8zOKJ12uRObJqYVjhebKeVpRS/znZ9Y6gasNm4zOGmN3RGH2AVw07upEp1hK@vFggzxJ5MxRQHJREIE3vP5Vc@/enp@evoZyCxocooG21N@MGJZfH78yb4GbTjxhdsDag9RxXZH2j4KlgUXvnudb3UKwlT7BOpHUMN9O1yvMXL72sEUmtGouPoO/qZPmtiqRzv9ZAHOCbRWecy43LVM@z04LYvh7ol2m5mVKpjMNosRVsxULqlmblSrlUZlwI@hrQahvsJIdM/BHHoc92ARLgW/wjUMwqFRSV2Xm5VpZApwGhWm6i8GbvuFEW@V27hp4v3KfQxcbsC7WbYqFh7GK0fkcueuA23/ieOZHeupNcIl5YdH21D94MKGWIdZyjY7o6N791GRvlarI@bMMXsyGcRMtdpUFq1Cn0ia2Ff9JF/RShscmr4udyos9rlSfgWfo20Wa2v3lbuZcjt2nzUUsEm96LzoMIPlMmU6zSyGkKAQEW3oSFylUv0KqDYc8HmpBIiIPD4HmBgTgLXb5GAqQ/u63Kr0WUxlU6YQeTLlbqWGod/gY1eV5bqq1t7UpaqqPpeqUE7Ls4hZ8SZN2mmXpZq6kcqVp2Cn5zPlHmSs@fm0PKoMoU1f7sOn6L3gC4rMMpATqAZgXr@Jvfvlbyi7arbC7coE6k0ftImG1qhMyw7u3QEsUUlXwCFey6QS2QI07rL5BFTIBtT7uUQ6kUmoebTVqcUHljroAbF@TGZMTqSmKU1P6JaegNL/wm6/YEriPAaKCNcElMTYPcCTgMEGMgm5kj7hbTIlbuz0GeSCy8xdldgUJEUZEwY077GhneghqGPL7FMIRVFZeifW346hn@3TyfCgVi@VDqbDr4JTTH11NxfPp@KvFaUc21IqnvVKqpalKkoVSvVwC3hWdOwwbzKoQR6Pt/W8UarVmpjCfCqRTqUheXbjTXdXrsr1RGorp0MOXTPSYxgXGFyXmWsjc7sGqtN4rDbTi0ZZ0mgOA8Wox4ziupUoioSz5wRAaSiEHVKYxc5kf0ldLBrNG9GoEi1jF/CWLHruQMLxE7pB1Ebv6Hdl0J/kklw00MNcUNKqqVRYhbqWsFnNMkUpciVdX13vQnszSZPZQD9kW2RSteo9KVJiDPS4M7EvR3KLsQ@dIxffrX7O32c4ixbgSrT3Vo3VaeaKZWMjiX2KK0TvsiggZo4GNcNI12tGHuo3kJm@V8PQy9jBHcHpuloVKO9dAX678SourvgKm83MuOpT9g5j3fi2RImOLJN9r7LXPd4r@1/72MF2JsmyXI7KkatoJHoNPylyj1Z0GHxFB4uE1nTwWaAtC@jzNkISg@1f@R0uJTwBImaWuHyo1ZW3T@z@VSGt8gY/CKzr68h2knJETIwvf@WFkYU8clx/pjw0fFAFh6orm8UOwkjyxdD7ulFIPz48ch6MHlqMT5QvZBpyNcJSuorzzsslYZvlE2XlYsGQjfNEhN2LlCPsXI3qJZpMz4Ynxc/znxc@f/zs6NnRQylytvVmy8XOY@aThb11vvxV8BhNZ6KMnVUi00qmLCYrVauqvmvgljd5hsesd/ScmnpT5exbJYecAS7vfvkHmeluAb4N0F5LkIXZuFGt6jsGUyLDd1/8AW51cHXw6d4jFvXMGfv7P/2Rkf/7P/3XNAUoel32qJsyHwGfaNRz@cjV1fDq6hou7paN1CMcqUxeATPvFdcj8/n6paRp7uTjGeOeU04Kv3peVyKeGhF9//lsxHsjnIxUAZz8znmyknOYBZGDYztr6Pd2kSn0YJkPm48BW14RuKLw@MUbxuCjVW13u7ZBpmSSld6qbPetusveYuf2W3WLvahUcUBWx8VBfl/uTrVaRSgsWo0nd6LMyIJb7bpcjzPqEIZW4OfWjrNztsjRZ1usWHTA3vJ2xPDB2Y4HTb0dh37WjufBp/9l7bz0mIwDHMlku017wOxaLFuF/N9JAjpnyrtf/k3DyP39n/7am8abxmcGtNyKxZxuRH6m/@xn4GHDqnS/2UWd3bh8HA1Bc42tORJYa0FLEc@J7jDu32@8YXMNdQa760BDHb@kC9RzKGsafKujdoy87eCi1QRpzbQRiVKWpEC7JK141G0lCAbbwe3aoWxKV9KX0AkqU1YBcSl9aQ4KLAZQfbqthtefjIY0CT5G4fR6gt2BIBDDl3AbqS1abCtkrgpiKrlzMyhH2SOqkU7EBpbn4aZUUItIX4IgYmstPIXWxHXh6NN2QMhr6IXwJId2DeKuQ9x9HqBBtjFKPfeQYBw7HsgBzVn6EigDRAUbdARm74KHMgiWLwEBIA0xAdius12WVtiVHY@X5zteXeOEYtxezPTXpEoYDKG1cQ20H7iM/sAKNHY8zAX5QuQwqGchSx8Ih8EHPCug82Nw@kKlixaNvzcogEUbtMQoaezOnTlWlYrdVhilCOGf20PsjqJ8cFbjCsD89tJH7ZKcYLiXWNm3DdgOKB4ndIHrVL6JWDkUlMn4eS1J8H9vpkWOXMoqcihjAkR@8VLRApJBYCQ7z8MW260w3cgrLEC@Bbi3CCnavipoBJ5NP9KMz3zHa8DwZxF/q2SQPqfhLj7Bt8uLkhlUexPcpxa3puHCQCwm5pvPoBQ7HPuhg1CQFLtPvjv2CBooNODq72QVS@sKBpvv/EV40BRhI8Nwrm5WwReFQt8M3ibu2STi2aJ9J1ouZKg3dB3a5Ik2pMBp0MARIKPEXjkc7Ylzifuai7yhwGGMPNonBzkfMaZNq@hAOAqLI5jNEbRifdokmNXVWGvQZkaRxYjRaE8fJwCnUCBCuAnaLtK42bcGgNKJZTHc58grJZNd0IomTdrY6LENfNV7aENV4nhJcfZe8tI@t5OnuC@r6nZAhRbLxCOoSGHx44OlYhOhvuues759bvGe29jCInuPgb4PSmsCKDu/gbAl7CQ20gmWAucE9wV3Hl55biwkQmG3YjPl5jutb8UamKNvqE6yR3iu3oXphOhL1xtJNHG9medv00GbTcC3FohcSyzQr0RxbXCw84QkNhyp0F4XGvbeD2PQ4PQ36kAj6OLWBcPGqoR1DAjNlr/kHUsxpPZLVAFQ2YOShXt2jUcl3KgBMBm1Yy0oekLAO@wjljYk9Mh3URE7ngAMzPrKInRwg6CYDm/chozR@PIqkCtQOgdtcMMlwoL9MLzP3Wim/dTm7M22BDisdCiuCuPFwv/Ihj6wdCA/U9K3wDEHGK7AZCsmxwFsXFZkDjoIvxycc7tEsqTEbkJKMIQgSA1QSFXwD95koQ3IJXC4b3p8l0qxu9fl5aVG28xNRrZmebgpt4eniSaHXRt0Yjc5tgZDcfyRjcfeCbhzk8r34sczZu9O6XTX4p0Zf0tSx6uIqQ2xaMeLYuV4gXtOdwe0PQ3uC@MRQz20ab/6VkzMxuD8Z9QTVz7/lZD/1EL0GoEwhmCmiVmilQBgiWbrPNG5bJeFwwUVSAAOuWj5lri148j/GHi@yR52Ah/umBYd@N/N/jkNYwIkmXedzqPmKfR9zvxP8T20pxDIsS7Z3mhkzmLkrqBvZODYjNQeNoNqn1zACNUMu@L7DNrT2qy@EHwaBIdKzW/ysBHuPSNdbQbKN51E9yl3n4L7lLtP55H60damda6SodU1Jge5Hrcs830imJnv55pv0Dh3IcigWDOdg0CfswW7a7hbFQrt05t/QT5WfMYAnhgCwa1Ysvb5We2s7njW5U49nuwCs8tECMhxAF2rE00v24EZqd@/6A9db8HKwZ3qoFYSeKNVqye4gfMKpjHIIGIMTi8bNxfrDsSAOlcIRIIBAuph4Iiqwd44ZivlYJdTcgTGqclzGnPEagKZOmlfwknYgbrESc8JGwZUDwFC@yBJgCa4ML/k8CMYfOnwfIQnTft@Vdo1foCb3ETrUaDkUlHhsqZMmRTCSlV9NIHsqK5WlpPiu0NW1JacQsm8FvkfRn/rg9HvQLlYjT0xLK8wylK4qOBcL1AhRHEhqrJqJZSvgEFyx@xbI6i5Drh@KmpriGYn6TczeDyYBO8Sz5WMhTK/pfD8oWVgsiOXAlaYVSqQxFmFF0teLnyScoIHwTwRbOYzggjPBQjASK0MZolg03CwaaXCBQebrgl2GUJySkhOeRDue7oGyboIBq2n4EBizJ46aKc4s0wGeDqvRkENGsoMD5fEQeqXuAEXjlKKOOcyh7hA8BCq2MhnrfrK2GshpENCawkAMuINAG1@mlNJWhZ4uhp8BTKKk9KXUfxLsAGXFcBgJILLfJPKWMBk1AYGhV@OUz0AZVeO1yRZp35d/KX4LSd8S//Wb1qmFn3qi5apxNLvH8WyjpQNFdCQ9qGnMiiQsSXzTBzDvaBzRPDgw54LWl3z0mWxFco22Cf9E7yTzb7bTA5MnBiCZ7wE53orfvsBx0TYvaE7NsduJlPijSab2G5V/LzNYHcdF5om4c1pQddru5bnRMeQqS2369ielcCTxLnKbtE0Bb6btxTWk4XR9SRJ9EHyZiyC5nyFqm6jgafONRoxnDumlIJJqTSVDNkzGpWw/QumUHgQTwLo0TDmNl9arbFyO0zcR1kEO7Vb57GjoXCMQiR7DGRYC/R/cO2BBsM8d95ypB1dUZVujmO0Z3zPHbhd0PomniZh6CXwh3PYiJA5HBIuCWZik7YU2k2bSkmslTAVEfQrHxyUfcWImUoQ3lgEsECMBBst0xgpO1oRXWNtdDyYH9/Jh@N7Esb3ZDO@1Apfxpk3zSvc8cOiTsfmEMDjHI307Whg0kFutW@gs4BKYI16FQ/w3ii2aeJVGzHdA697wrvWAf5IBF8efAWIf7qO/psz0A9@8L7ZZ@JRnCczkDcDnA8Yo938PX9wMwbeDxVFiqyILmDtB@8ZF/jFg1QeogoBaiwJLgc3o4SCOYRmtxdske4DvoXncf7UDb6nSVUV7rgCp9FFgp0b67PoQaNt9c2Z1Y4Jn4kQXD/Fx9BgI3n1fglHQUdCz@VtvRjUXUrgCtU4Ep17Kq1hGTNxoSjr2Yp7sQPuoZ5ywvBwPf3Q/YZoxi6@Cu@thnZANIobozkXNnZ/DmfDGd/vuM8PYRBylNc/PCdxsfvtBAE6iO1eEvNolU3i8zgWJOk9aoTAr7aYZNyO1IeIO33ezMMPI9HtKYXMDQWq@LksLe7dvzrH7U05HuIKnyf5uNH7seRtTPfePBdiNQ5sLsL2P6wKuQEZ52O0WrEwRG6zMcdc54ZMQDvqp3PW1CqNFQI1CEmSbmxTc5v0C0XClvEhvLHD6VN4I8CuNW5whvLThn1a4nQURi4DcxjSWoQNKOkAJURFTnKBRsiX5JvB@9V1EGdrbZytG3G2FuIMSsBilCFPUmshSpELmD2bsqBvdcZrpDM6YdsZXpvENlyOa46wt@IqakdLdoJFL6IlEMhRK1o6iIFQjrajpQdk8KKlEzKcR0tfAcO8bEXfREt@sUAPI/gkwz20FyIcv1vR0n5MuZbG5rnl@fFq0VKQp@DnLv8kigApMN2gNeIQm@OKZI5HFlRspFQmGHKMl8DmE/XDJOhOwZ@fxkG7@qMj9nHukGcWZ/pCpRGqMXg8UG34u0avKMklUZsfHD2k@UyBF4wmDm28cBgCD2p4JLoojDhi6EojGvAGBFFullZjxEI12XuiI2IHDqVMXoyfqKeRPtCOkXsNPNfnkdARLCK8n1@LIHgGvh@eGHgdnjfQ8aMjjHBMVlmBFhL1RXRDojCvF3ERuR/OIerrXvSEZ9n6XnguEdiQTAcdjgbnMLKhO1xkEnLFKfF2OAx1yvFCidy7FIykgiiZa5zJWqQMBUO48CubkhMKh6gtiCB0rKXqvJQF9QLJYnSay7qQpsoLH6AQkjlQwq3WOR1v80AYyR8XNwmqK9ZVQ35YHiVJrkUxCYE13LVnYo557EHj9QD38vmw5qsfcop9LTEEEAoZxMLlq/sB@rvL9XdfofaJsBTBKsV6dVV6U73eWMsuYd6fR3szA9ExwR4oK5WjIIY5yaF1ENLMN/HaDRUfp3xwJZ9HGkBf0vZ9sgVtglvotty24LBQSxhdLFqeG2B5bqwn1E2NpH@h@UqLhjEJODzhAabzpG3GlSd8VRajC/Vvm/0PzuDRYgaHMw/hUQJGSyTnpXw0cWiWy7xsg9jmNihS9RLjgpyGS4NsnluCuKeh22DYFiyOGscPjp48@hpUuvl8XhF19GyOH5Za7GsN6nEOmSZHB/XBimaLkcATK3CwG7vj6dzorTNHviFLuLAGZcCEWHz2E2VcEbIsJM@Xyi6E435DFBWwzufFwFyQSqjqmFhl24KuYyCINY7tmAKIr94CvRPUWlPobIZGA88KbjSo@mo0cPJSoyFqMcwaf0Rc@VlkKznxRnRWIT9Y5FKSaLk9e3DEnn@yd8pOPzlgD5/tf4V97egZe7735BSXTT99dv/R4T6D@@DJyQGTFqZH4iFM2KAEuj6wWhYelodbnmUYQd53hzMud2L7Crc/MQfsE7dl4TDVrmcO7vX4h@ZY4yoPdQDN0Rn2Ydp00NbAHuN8CzolCpqxqNy0ackdzuVn4LcJbdoBtnkHbtvu2OBXwrbv0LY8f@UX69uQgyBv/YWtCa4k4YFQNHWIjm7DGViXENwE/zh2A2BMPv@KjmO2PR7AamtMEC64PpiCpwfHj08YLszfP3ry4PD08OjJCXt4dAyfT792@ORjoOfhyenx4f1n6EQeHx89OHx4uL9HFhyBlMZwafzLiTfeiIKG3okqrXMc@aZTt4OvxV5v1ODZpUmLDz0WnTgofWyzb7@22tGyNPFQfcEFjzRUwGLbe8cffwp1PrNe4QinPxRM8w/kZx4dTLadYrsUGxSWKpS3siiuUO2pukLjEYMZw3MKrDKtgo@ROcF84DSJp21bTN7HOSrY980Xy1NZ9kFDRFsAG0H5E1YqjM4XiUYTuwSyCrG1@i5ud8hj45MIxQcGvedPNSlLRDExVwaB4nqFQwf7g/RyYAF8DxaGiHY84h5YOrDgHliGW6AqeohzR1hW@JiMjyYonlmOW7wcDB/SsDDLBxb3TWrFFgROPN8oS00WnM@EWwf06RQZ3stDp9uZXsu2KYhH/vGElX6fFwyLn@0FMpEPJdLcNvApg7Dp4FCDmPbGT8FEV@AGnCdkdsYei1UUjZ3i5CDLsfn5Pd2@6fApUPOpO8R7rICbw1TENFs7OPeGVoAMXWJAPHNrEY8g3AOhFVrvGw5C3r8RoynmSNLZc/4UtNsQuH8DgZ8HDABSF1o6LaqpaI0pgnE7gpVjngscif22b8P@gZ3bk5a1EEDM2oq9tF@/VgSREwvtJH@eImEHWfTaGoFaSUOZHXcEZZzEKp0UglKw1XOHY5vnYWwxBTTiRNUc@MaKDWJ7UakuxIZ0WI7RcZ1QpE3g4jWxNoEp3ydW4ng@dh6Ir/mxkcD5UAnzeXeIjtnEU6fnY2cJHES6tLD7BRRhGivHzs/ZmDDh@qc0lx1vGZ48V6hUH9w/U9@@SODxc1ws8BMf/UmHeANjYlxQPGicjyYsjlDvEiXNPzbImzQxtJiDJ6QllnIfGLQDeza06@41yoEbn2580x7XyCzbk@WbNxUeSkXJJA4B9XqxuXRLsJofZYLC1JmYAhKSnYAsyPqYb5MgmIG8vofrYjAXykARB@UIttuXDuURIsRPXXPSAckizkYU2R3AV1iVZlTMj4rFlS3h/Eh@HrtfiVeV5HxCCQuRM@aL6IQPWVeU0LQUqq9ugHuwGRzI7/cHV9iIHa8ePgjag43QPgg3Nb4eFq@WQrDeH@zbDWB55fZzgYW0J9YD5pXkTWgBpwfMmdiOBLNpN8f44kbeUdkDMFj3Yg9KADQU28ShIWp/c@EYD6CEwcwVopPTBwfHx0zm7RMIC3IPmwxtIQYR9hZ7Op9tazsk7LRAaQoay4Hy5NsszGjzr02FeSXx1ogKoYMkBD0CYTE/FLljT7nUEzULqRA0@54Eok@5ReyufBnk1QTga2gDArLzTAslUFqZzAivfGwvPAlc0C3BdePwHH6aYc3rbjxxcDQLAwrPCTK7uLJkdf495/pxyY@HK1i4rw0muA2aNNQ30E44gYiH4FHTFnNwQ7b4WYqT7LmCHfFphxO/Uosa9i/OUMRIXAnnunBIrAvlWKDG9eNtX82hCYlYDZg401M48hnN4OCLeLLZDWeoMq/0YotVECiZeAbdvTBXQPD6dTk4FT02rycrgUIeLmvbhE3Nx7KOvbMCdnm9p49wLnRuWTwsRwXSdmNU6j9MVLyWWIjJp/nKxPiOADmXzaZvg72cCj@4@ovC5nXIsvwcD4bQvp@D9Gbe/1Pcs221jWz5jL6ikEmwQJZtEgjBmLQBk7gPlxwMSbMMcQtbNjptbNoyYHdg1pl5mB@YeZ9PmF85/3Ce5ivO7EtVqSQbkl790FkrWFJV7dq1a9dt34rE@8C5tUNXpccM8Azp2LReDZhUQdjqzFhTEm2nxcjED3BhuRAgg0G98Vq/dK2OGKdwmw2dVyQTOmWZaoMxhHVDedRMUf/x@epwQv5mffO/vz4ebJgJTQcf0Sr/YDCMgtgrz4iiYnxC/9Xkt2A47FM29me6RihZcmN61tmOvO3Y4JVbhYmkbzNb0pHeSWx26ypZA1VC4kUPb/JE6V4pLd7LFUtmU/dq@1WxRMH2OglZpD20HWPumQ/7zyFAczDJJXD5IB@@F9EG/AccXAUSyETefFmijfNN3IgisGtu0EUr0ixUzq3FdO93opbfx5Aerv0iErb7EgqSFLZ6tOfMkqwXSonygFx0089CKdfOeTYVhW8o0EVISRDcm/jdWLDQU0NZSj5z/7qfL64X1t5a1Lq@O3KvG28v3KVW2Raw@Pr96@h2eN/@pTu4uuuInrj52@W4NfntVyFWX4tXUNfKSw60Wlwr5ylK5Rv4uy7eFohzJYLvKGjsuS2Ex3e@CbEo4nN4aV7wfWd0aN5AD4kUl4qla8WF6GI3Kl831i7K/XKhdN3oX5TQyW@0XB4tF5ez@OElrKIwx7BmvjG6wDXVlLoG/TuBV4HSlW3SNUSQawh8OfCH4WC/cvg@IY3DDQCKwKStNwnU@RbPObRmQ98Trx/cZ6WYzBXIsRZukKw58goqok87yZNRHNMOATPoFRd2s9GY/k4ca67g3d6MBpSiou8ha4mH8MGaU25MBZIoQJZGqGL00eXl0TjOk0XFEH@dsBV1rsjbtSL6TjoGiAaWpOnQPrdt9ClERKUvV@PCirzAb10hEnht7QMVE5ubdIktsFrkkRQPTTn8ITlMFC7wERUg8HND2gasgnbuEbl9WNB8fC/iA38hGdWI/GTIQN6inSKmoPm3@Er@TVR@EwjAhJ/jPZcnRZxy5wUbSfYdJOECBiJLHvxRzYBuldwpc9hYhM31lWPgZClONMJqJZng@9w9kpNpBf9kC3JFeptqhs7vcHYiCemp5VuEtKQupaQt/OnFxbJGsZwqpjIbpJj7JjVQ0gXHo4MAhtVE7AS9HiDNtJiLyYGP5N8r61/W9UcNrPNCI8/puan0XCLd43RGKs7lwQIfZ9owM9mZr3G@R2HH2dypusqCNi8e9HTLgy1JnLf0XN7IGw2aYZx5S3clc6VO2Ewk5IyULzN6n1PmE2U0g@v0BqdL/l6RPa@xTOT9IVk//lqygwIynpW2Jiku9fph7x0vWjoF2cwGagrBxbG/ie14UEofTDmdwA4O5fw0bLfKMZTloppxaMzYW5s/2J7cZLzLptFgL8apgTVjjBhUojqXiXBjcliEeih53gBBMJHRhBq5W6rwRBaeGGAx17yqlr0gpwY4NC09xMvoF/mAf9RgTyKn8mVmJ84x5mNuPHs3JwlEk@68PZtMydkE3UX4o2zUM6tIXPckDXH2JHFoSIF1nQH7YHdQDD6v5wlzolAzxRTddYqkdJyhqNj3qS7ExEfrX/kl670Pe@ybXjAWFTxm@OSFZSUc3EdBNIowthPFoolub256qHWkDd89uVDLQCErq6huiSEaK7tn1dCyh/O7@CQd0qGQJ44Q8j0aiMQJ0W23i85k6AE7uMepFSUu4cizKv0JCzRgzLxaYTfzQNxGrDWF037XRIJ7jkcPUjq68VuBZ8EeLYLdj8VN7fD4lvJ09BvB6GGwpG1Y1l9vw9YvO@9Rn/umWHhVNEh2J9XBBe/V69jBCoikElYKsI1dLb62LEM33GLdcA4BumIfF/pPwJvBXdDvB1YFVgzKGMGmNQqGd0Hbs6zjQCuBES6yMmom0Q97cDtssXAHNl0@MCN6CUcuq8OAw/AX12dWF7dIV@ZaqLSKtc3Q1XdhGwmoPE46A9QOk8ICwwQwPbDQdTACoiw5IokS6Z4lLrR3uUZBFFAD45wYuglNhv5gFLagZ0iSZfUAFKtB4sr67RQmUF@r56NzsDcLAXSPiSmgEFCqpOdwsKTS/HfhIGTDlI7dVz2Th9lvQGMFhnswDGH2jQlMvULFDNyhg08@1OqifrR38rlyXBXw/PH46FNtt7orts9Ix42KcopoKz4c7cPsorXprDU/gg92pQ4lbUqwKodnovrTx@NqvS6OjkXt4ON@DaAB@OPK4UmtWndF7XBn/3SXtO8AQRwenYj92kHtBLKdHLlUqypmxeXE0Z44qB7vfIDXynZtv3ZyRjXu1U4OsTLU6lfEx8rxSW3ndL9yLD6eHn88qlcFNszardV39iu1g@quB/VDnaL6qXp4IuofKvv7qYYefT6sHgsyEjBauV0FLCvbcITFmqidu7Xj6s4JNih@2gHiAYL7rqh/rO7U8KH6UxWaUzk@cyXQevWvp5AJEsVu5aDyHhpnZb9BFeiXndPjKsY/QkrUT7frJ7WT05OqeH90tEu0rlePP9V2qvWSsPaP6kSw03rVFXgZHFUNMIBakA7P26f1GtGtdngCa8bpR7R3cKCTPwNhAMsKFN0lAqMZBLYWiHR0fIZQkQ7UAa74/KEK34@RpkStClIBLSp2TsxsUCEQ8cRspjisvt@vva8e7lQx@QjBfK7Vqw50WK2OGWpokHEGrAOVnlKrsZ8AL34EZrUU57rUnaK2Jyq7n2qIucwNHFCvSW4hsu18kDT3MBquIUQJBygz8K9NwUpn@tNdgMElpyUys2U0OmLSztFuFVZkGazKjhNOYdVZT4VSMtNgpdGJ8JoIWdMOLm@7zbDfGaCPqS7Ggo/rqOvirSoOXi5xbj1zeYWUr1CBTKbZ/FRpwkG33mw67veUTKDxrRJSDP5cLke2EePl48kbBT8bG0z3zQShtl5KRScZ6qECAnMy9V@y6Zt/HTgin28Hshg67yNgJTqKWG1yhaoUmBrJ2RFvwIirJMkEvYeSHahgVoH3Wk2Uk6JlJGUaRPCn/xC/8OJgfIDZmcVd@TweYgmN8LdAVcOVUEgE@iMjEoQdqtKLguCXbrZgVodnfq87GLSzjqPKUN4RnAO7WecbxS@Dbqp4Ll2ekCW1s4ygH6lzN21htP5ZkkzIfvGG1LIs/mmO6MdR2HDMB5SaUlUkrJZCy@xLLo4WSa6QoS3QvYI6Gfd8B5Wfap/xNFdYeV1Kff@gv/PYQntBDEILC16Dyl3Qz4cLzgADjGJxAElCGSEjnzfKKHsTnfkeMl5hpvuwjZY/sFZfBbSuA0lgI3vr98w6cTUehmMTe5iH3x9XDrZP9/Zg6kRsX6@vvlkrWTrs1k8u/55hPRQplqKO3cA6Dvs0SjJGyQ5sfGikGLG0Y/YnBs7nMSNGV1edRh8xzoO220haMuFEhs2N8DqYPpro2QHSwRYUgGPeUvw6c2RKBsgmmupga679MW3xfdgrEQ9IY5behHptjH8Qth7@aojrBkkGkixGsXOBc@F0QfOevadMRelwQ4F7MItnKz7mMG6aBiTqIvtZ9K6lN8nbRi9GbMqI45W6nUoCEvNpLISyq@jzyP5IcUakAJiih8GXnyS/weOZDHBH4e78aFQZ1YGMe7okyqljYbRsdENCvtgqQxe9fKlr2hQo5XckUjT2pDhZBwYxRgOhgpeBoI1vEnBJxxFJV0kWsD8sOuIrcyoG70A4Jcmx8h04d1ZzJJSSih8i31VUCsGwdJATptq9rsNSWc50HAtFzgSZ/hA9CP6fSJMZ8DfhxAnQY2oZQQC/i5IElWkFx1ciSnivFA2GdiOmpvnpLAbzaHbMlW6Y1N6M2b8GSCB7Z6I@nFHYw052BgGQyVGwYY5fbZJ25cPR6QfbkcVRT9JvXd9khVwr1FIxBTe3duHStstVuhV8cYTDsiajwn0oKn7gg9sljXo4MqWO8uJFZDM4R8X/yC@RAEQPeOLSK7ZaTXNWQY4yNQ/IUEvGgtPWEZNgW/r4pNZuSRghMhNzv9R8KUIB6C3EZ7qddO3HQLB5bjLiIq3E4oSi4GE8cDwm4@IjQ9ZdkiFmL0A4L9okDMGbQUb3uED0GDqF6ouhiewLMhTBSmKrwzjOIE63jgekpWX1XmNPkknkUI39aZ8D0Qcs1VI5PA7wITE03eU9ceBPAOXe9zWbWSy/VB@4aLuIlbFYQpbHW1Bag8EQto4@thtwdMOJ44nPUugQ9KPboYxfCOtZOJQSCbXph2pw28Snd1pmOAY8oRaFI/RWaHvEH9Sk6wAtRDk8yTi3JrLAvIpHt5TQMRwvF0V2M07ZBJpQWFIi4qZYEw8PnIsJKkOGBkTBMNKHC7LZpHpQ76CH3/1g@Auu/bgF6reDto5MaoAkWSB3Uq1PMR5bI266uv4JugIlIJoSRRakaUNVWKPfSHaSdk12HB0TY5dSS35/PZpJlbUUVBQzrqwdmG8tB52JVFqRoUF1sNDiyiqhMuvA9fjkYYyihSbV1sI@7@spZYM3EeUXauuITzxv6qczfJJC/vKLCEcPfEEdt9yCIsK4Z0W96vQ8R/ihTcHnMBi2TZko7GTa/g2K3@joM@gTLyrRoQz71/JHUTCBE0ArH47zBKOZ/XFw1W/uDHp@NxyEPpzTMIz7mGc8fJzQI3ZYdzi4j@iCH0poG5nak/iZ48twGDZ813rJkhGaKxoFN1nTTGE0nFSuOEwESc7RCDC@1pH4@yYdI02Xeb0aF7KS/qdkj1d0Sk@WfVWcVZg1@ghATnBbKQsK9iEdkWOS4Xxamspw@VwGA8dLkRO@84TFXgLjt0AiUsMkMFbITJklmI3Ak9mTGDfaY7dNMQiHGGgp2A3wypkoS59dHy/QhVnkHVoKbIjiesEoylqUMcYhxIfJ0@ReefMnYw8I/AH0i69mccssRqAprqOiLUV8XpFRRgEXMg8MaY6mmRhmsbALq1AvAbQ5TkNNJk@eogZZ/sCmSIbZm@JKHJFZOPjgnXHZJkw5zYmDi8qiWHQobgduQSqjbOFphg2@ZT9Lgx@VuCw5w4lpR0LOGkg/RaoWUAnvCk2Z15ooc0zlb4@YlZXv7bUUAcuzTM6MO3Gzttq5kAdKyOsrqrUGQ5iM7RT1pKnHYjQa3Cx@J/WenDtmRmabReuW43zTEJiZrQyL5VKbSFue4OOkZKXxSTFNkmJkaQY8hMdXetZsnibiuNzE8VZuTr5Bh6doFttN6UVF93ebxz4uindo0asWGj2kCHcMUlrS3xtNaHjz6RlEwuTjVZNmjCZOGc0JPxqgUmTSVPp@ChH3SdxT9GgD5bDeNtDO7J8niZo2klMhT1VSIsgl0hMDt6PTJsxLNx00vsAwcbzD1ZOU3nCO3Qmp8oq5SwwyjAkMEHfFQS6WQ7EEN@6sFB/R7QCdbBOthYo4E8HTlmnhoIP@a4JRVH4p3JEWD81JrnhRYkhjDQlOFZTrOUjK3xxeG80xQZkiBQzxGaTQLZqam66@v1V/tC2QDyBwaUqWlr4FFxvjiGXABv6YSc0x7oHjqmTJxIhKDoQmTQ0wFuCU0u0FfFzF3V84ZI5H6wY5jOAAwZ@z@LMsS2A477WCpjYWGbcnmMWR5ObR5ojcFheJGYrfkfxyKPJWlw6uACBgjKF8uQgQMKwpYY9KAQq9Y3JeAlHZR1CwXMRhCR8pKmps5zkjHYkqM7xeNXIUZuV4a8LIzQQCG4vZeWJEYM8yO0sMBRa6mbgYOd7Mbk@cAzbEiveZ4tAVsleSNNQ9xwSER8JWzyiNonALkoMp8fWqk0jU/E2pbwtGaiGdCvTRGDZyxXTqeiGRmqh2ZSVZNFES6OGYtSYSgRSOibCeFf7YP3JNMUOea5tQ45CR2GVI@@w@HqXu8dzm/S0Sm@SUrfYYCp7pGa6OX02@YiURlP35AOxikVQGGLv9D7dWWaYqTORdARSXTjm7ZPlASDtWG5d6bBaedFWkPR2gQJ1pBx3x6WRvLxH29XKiDI2ug@FqoVBAJr40g98r22oUJYWDfDJ3vnPb6@Vv7n8cfrrM09wfBHQlwIY6QQfQJTAoIm8w7PLNEIgDZMXcOenIimf9207HvIIBNZTYedBtnFNGQxC0AIXa6OXTCQmACKRcYH/GBmL7fhZ69N37vNGUUJQaCkqjSfCdrbRnQB780EH7bK2pImA4MStrJli3nPLWV1xB8GYT6iwKX@x8jc2T7Q9BrzdwxWe8IhgjBcw9pgvs7ZkFCpwFNYzk3XsbUTxaVwR3Yc/wK8YsJq8jOLUwqXsmVFx4jI1/HHSr45us3fhiw7ICTV7GZi5jfGpX2F3bkcHivwMs8yGg/V25r/2bbIvolM4MS70cwfETYPSq6M48@ySyOCQTkzT7dm4k6mx0PQrWAE13aC@gYtlT91JLnsiuiWufj4sdpGGBYUicMObK95VAV7M/b1q8G3U63zcr0jUA3LG/a0bkm1D@2IRIOgAagXL4AT0xivZfcjCs91IBRXiDg5d1TM87WKCJBSzrRav86322UqmIhZvlZVGpbMNDLicq2xWxix@2t8UuvG/j@8vyyupqiefcXecrfNxWHx/FNsAgCedy62q4C6@QVka/MbTWxi5eyJcX3NJCs7y5VYryjco2uvXD0z///T//@R//la/Il//Bl216aXzRmTzPyy@0vi68fCzhe2P3YnHhsrFwc7HYLSGX/Yuihg9qo5wfm496w0srw6uA8ZXsSNU5m6LPyKJC3ep37Q9/gdllQ2RaUT4jv0Z8cxTNsZlWYHwP0I/yEo7w6tKB9FEekMgA0AmK46F3WgEa4MF6A5QEXNAOlMuzbkUJ7jEcjM6gtSoZGYmH9qx3Afq0xJEU0BcXVqxc2I@CPkrA72jPy82zLB9@w1FT8m/@y0HU3R6MxdJ5ViwVxJIrlmybfoprb@Grs5AP0TuXs8FxwLZdSIlVC2hmKKKQNnp0fqC7dlLktqwFurIHIakwFZSZveBcffojZxm@cC3qWnN4aaZgEQkpmbBI5utC/xG65SvkeLQTrja0UWjKUwxVZmhUdP/iFsiP2BAgrvmaCbIxgCpR00ceyfiUV19kX1t0mxABRrIev9@jcY8fYC1a6Eub58RZCq85IvN5/oprY4mdoQltTOH6YwRIocLHyQJ5Ei5mFi228jZaSc1kL2yzfZL52NZhEoyUbToX@jdhMAFbc5uEW@hLvxZpyM3qFWGHWr1iVGWnbb@FZRS5vu2NwhvprkC144D6qmt75JGEPUqAGA7H7N@YHmEkKFCRolLdwpdlTUR7gE3nkdCXrunQwY7HmiODCPkvWRjbD6mx7eTJS0SxA/MAIaVN@Tp@2Itk1JUhEbvrDy/xdkC/QxeqjVhvRvI8vCY1hfGgo5H2CDKZnMfjGZqSuRn63WvfFZnDwcnQn9Rg2YKdz6jlOdBCDMGESODgk1XPap5CmFsku4QooptClkN4eUFvIq9H4761tc8JdqkaCjLsCg6CBDsRJYOHRF@l6Bhz9e/oBBPlqclbayPlFEszL1oaSUi26TZDw2xq6FiqBnPs6IFjW4yqHpmKF2ShW1xor0nxCzN5D2MEyLpt6QUoXRHW3mL9uDp1g76fWJxuepZy9M@XBK@LOJ7pKkq2RrLUzafF@MY7xAr2kV@SUSB4bVLhjKy5bHbuPJLXuWXMdYSCfGtb/LwvQn0BHV1gRp4h4rQf8mSZWqHiOzA8USPLf4DQ6fldwG9y70@QFc8z2Xfzeafx5bx/sZQ97z@c/@YQJnJKVqtsTmSkMlvNWHKswMqYdxOvyiotUqEGz/vJDOd9wT4sBgkAkXy28SV/8ZAHhM4zeKf8eYYJkugyxCT/fH15BJ@fQjOTxCKfseacJUd1fvZd0RGwttIv9iF/cPgXsFCHShLTwzln2AFQ5Kf76y27nET59ZXC65XiazgJdYNxbhjc4nqbi24vgzFsJSI8zsLSc/5bghsShHgcR34JPo6hnXytCfueRNJJSU6hcphTPZZmKyjjMU9AfqAyhUtFFxdH5/FR@YgHflcAy6m8FAuKTQcN7svi@hkNrrEeP8J5Le0dwhyJVgZsI0Ii1BxCVpevPMWhjhoui@Tn5IkdjN1KQKB78xljtegP@jm5WXO8xRJuotFrprdeWC@kx@jUEE2M0AW5mVqcF8Wtd2/@8d9Hv2ZGma2V/Och/I4yv2bW1jP8CA/w9kq93WW2MpuYbe0xM8nDGRge3/zjf6H81o8AB1Mmm/Bna1XBWptktnJlKvKQ2VqDh@LKCtT7f3//O7RhgU9seBfrQtMVhFhJUWTH7xPvQrqoYSv5WLoYTyvkmIUw2MIQzubwgoZR45X1AonpMtKq4i6Qka@UPYpc4skwa0SmQizJUPYUsDPiAmWsIMcglQlFRxi2G8psA5k3RlP8/MJbi@AE8LM059BVatONFxGaDC3wsQg6MMs1wnmeH7YK72xt3rFhK5uSktpC4tFOzrXrr0r/Dw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/14sar)

IE7 is separated from IE6 with `window.XMLHttpRequest`. Space before `?` is for Chip.

Answer (score 4):

## 307. HTML+JavaScript (IE8), 14333 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa






























































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.innerHTML=
257+[10,0,0,0,0,0,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:8][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]
}</script>

<style>
*+body,text{display:none}*{+color:fff}
a,b{-color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
b{color:000;-top:-90}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[ s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1 ,8ute_[2]!!\0/ad4ocod"r"n;z c;p>s0}e}tfeqFloat67+body?4
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRfoxvu2c8215PxHgndtbtHXsmwv464ZhP/gHyY2PDseH@B73nnMwqFEgAlNp2xMbGFlBVWfk4efLkyZMn303T6/3sZxG82FO3P@v23TEbW96YtUf2uTXS2L0Zu2vaXtZISxL62h11JwPLGXslKcJ0xryxORqzvul0J2bXYhGwNdj8u2P3x9YowTzLYk2r716Ae5oxx7pgB07LbgMkNnbPLMd@Y43ALcPYfav/dvB2zFruYGA6bY8NR7YzJtcsY09N@OhMWmfMbHrjkdka264DTjnGnjl9c9Bsm4y8D0cWD5RnAKp1RmEWXQqMPXZHngUxuC3L81y0LIKlObLdR7tPPr3mX0@xT01Aati3ptei13X23LZG7eshDPb5yYMH123T7DPVddiDmyjpGbY7GbsH4@vws2y3azkmM7SiZlx3zAExx1a/kCqkFpzA7YE9gtw0Ra6V5jnjTAZNawTEF1l4YY97GgQ4cTnBmev0Z8yaAjDAsQPerDGzMbdYNpVCn/A/tlqu056DBysL4ABcazAcz5jKHFfwADi5I@YNzZaltq2@PbDHVpv1bcDO7QhsPAYZzs6s2YU7goxXOSsSIt7QatkdG4OIFHgSMtt9qznpMncyHk4APY@1bc9s9sFbc8baVsec9McJ1gQ3IB7ZX/QsR6BkO11Mx/O5DUJwoAhw7Dd1oI3d7zNA5wzRwag9to0OF2iPXpsWYWm1EdT@nFwAyex7fuoXI16IBsM9HbndkTkARm1bRIPPD54yr@WO4Atu9MtLwTowLXPMtrdZdP/J/SirBmTURk0pIGmFXTLGIr4jOzf7E8tjA3MGcTtjKFzMpfzzQ0jgnUU3oiUWTaeZkWKZDMtAYSswI5tiUCSKYIBSa6R1uHPMKLCMDnyfjSYwns7I7Np9i0Ppuv0OAsojxxpZZsAzlYkmuGuL4sizdIHl8iyfZXl4FlnRgEgQYobpxSzcObgBQhEw0OFOZ3hMAVsgO0ES2B7rmAO7P@PQh0ME32JZneUBIqCpA2SjABCKBkJYvMLwxj0gbM88B5Bq3z5DcWEFEgNzKwmv5NZWkkQWykYepdez@n2MFQgFJMoWWB5izUGiMxAz0NEoGH7iuz1KPuGVT8ENOOYhxQUgbwoolUJS5eGGbxBDBsgbA4SLAfLC0MHeAHMaoYK/HLjlIK9yAWmNNtEWpCuE1ZGYKFB0pAEEY5B16QyDzMtA9qYxe7NpBngCAvkcA5lS0Fkhwwp5BuQqphiQXgdkMO91kGU6IKEjMMhSHfJUB0R0YBYdgOrpLJNCdNXT6A5h0xAWSKBnIEwGzJAveg5vCAcZr0OUOsRpGMU5awFuRhYSmU0Tzxk5yLw8uAGxDMDVAG4xAFujAO4YtgCEKyBL5n1CmP1hz0RaQA4gIwOrAUGygBPBBv9gNvJpzlLku2mN7ZZ0JUGp4jVgWOL40gMlAEgTZjKsQIEB59wTCySgAgJpUVhNPKsPXAQypGWCGdkWSjtKDh@OPdZQzkI1ZbnnWJFS8V@IxiMR0RxhLQryqm2NRgz9QmXrJUiYeJOmZ72eYF07x6sD0skCwdox7X6AABUdc0z1ALyjHsQ3W0S7M3IHVL4GKCz6rjtcIXZBNF0goIfuhTVHfS65zOGwD/Ic7C0gxMTsAzIXJukDpC6EY@UIQSAM1@rZAJCiArlqj6wW0V4kHUKnQQIvolhiRvVOGqHcC1ULaTZ0Qah6GMaZ9PslqO6sFktXk23rPIk2vOpYrDIQB78ygfpQgGiaUJdTZYpYBJDuGBpVUyd@znruYDFpXLwcBEnv2VgF9C/MGeReBySLNTUHoHEwrNYdqLgHwDE8BzEnPF7xHLC260THAZSLEVSvkOggJQCyTzQZ2wML9DEXgmCOZwhpFG6EWXMGrEzUymikjnFMrhFKk64TiltkQha8sEDF1p60kGoYt@0QB0GF4FFtVQW4XOnU0ABFbmSZbe4NtQvEKKQfQW1nAdGFKtAiQKihWI4H2o6nMRvVQmD4rtsBHqMqGlQNCDqPp0Vpx5QHVlOtpUlEaeSbwVmf2aw1HDKwB/0E0HqQKkAd676y2Rtw7Pc81m9NRqMZmw4hA@wB@Bq33E4HmPaNNewBCDZos9asBaUSUolMI7VdkkCt4bUkB1@bFvhxLEj23tOvs64F1IYauQOYEqfPEzAcUhKIFKbDa2vHBEphElrDGZEFwAQhOq6roX3btTziEdBmghKPkXlWl0oEFK/OXAYNUPsA5gSNwAGWBYEjShXCxwilpYnBqETmf2o5UGJawIxQ1iH7UB/dZR3Q/UOVNSp3ZqtlDceCPVySYrYTUmgOH6BCQ7aqAKZ5PWnzLuhiCxhI4FXyOSdUg5tnJFxR0Sc9y0QRKxoYUKc7VqDCMi5Q@rMb0YOP82uxyy/RzwIGL@UVOAypJKB2R7JhMkYJgkLRbvVQBI5RyJCWAYVsNLmZfLALRz8aMLUTxI3Y6CBtJC0ZWCEeq2GocPdvAtKGfYRVXbBArwsWt4A2vcESyG6AZL8dttWSpgay8DagA9dxl0AFYgZw0cuiC@UFMeMxSg2zHzAjFRdvIY9QTs/bvlh/QdU5HLojKBlc6MxQkvEsC3GXy9spsaCKUKDdvFijQk0RxXp@POZtrmEf2kFUxLCkgj5pgqQAIcZbACDzXB5jCGEq9QRL4HdBEp8zE1ShjmOhSmqOZhwIJA9qZYhoxuzRCMTgOdYNvOrx6xCN@BSqArPdRsmK5KByfz1yDTl6b9K0p9ebGS201F550rk5Yh1sYYxA14BCFIt2vKhSJnsKGXKSk@5wnKSg/CmDR/KkQZbHOtBogYrgAQia45nTiskLRUxOMHky7hRkBQwYkKtm7KvmcHwdu1dgh0wzOINyTV9l1oVaW1XhqaIdYYIOSQ0dzBGoF1AIQcsuFttNk70F6TFi6nSPQqNaSG9dywRxWU47iEsQAnEJp1fjUXijFhnUUK2GKUDvlHKqJBYI@IGUoIAyWCSTov5EC1LyuBupM9xy4lD3AItxDURhl4GKDhVAjJCxQeewW/a4IbSUO3d8fWWjUgFmAyUKxGZbCSv3fj@KBpIaPGukhIhItLF7PMayEVMgvej5imMD2hJwaqXKLse9EZQ4@r6SwBOQVXKQk33Cinx@Yp9N2tcz2kFL9CRjqQNdyW6N5bIElT8vDZV1VI0uUBWU/yhSFZkXwxPoG8xLtpihsvA2sjzUeisClVAOxxADwatLScSDCrs5Q@/NWn2hEnATFHYujZqA/ploqQeCKCF0Ar/Q3iipHAgWBw6HPd09eVgRZZE7Jpu2U1qw6Lsts0/Wm@hd9sM@Orh3tHv09cYSGH27WbpukbQzhRxWtZOp2nUmyYxmlDbDMOaA7zfWw8aAi35kSTgz1Z2GVKVZCyqXqU/Ow6PPrpMENCEkB8UAZryvqTTcDyhdUtP0etcqYdaNxyHKIIjvl6kHzIcZGBB1dDd9fJ5O3rzBzLuO1FDYI2b9ickB@JbJA8cPp6HjNQXMd2p2eI1IYUELtR3s/5ybwj59fD5Frfk6MqRKh1jm08MH@0cVAtszvTOr31fJS9Ibgy5ljtoa8Hx/0rakZX5A/IGpxeLaHHHUpwnXpQRutRYIPM9btgI@AMAmjuYytT/wk@b1APe962kjW7UVcAB9E4TremVYH2p9LKIhPLCKa2FLd1ktSg7zyiqwWlpjBa6L1VYrm7XymWK42mrN42yHgQ5IKbZdX28cgdOZp6KNNtcihVot0D9@dANxj5RIaAqoPmZen2kUl9eXsPWi2izqJfegheb2Le05STyZyUoyGfU7PrWWR23OkP/9qT2OpRT@1hXwC7Hv7h4Y933PoqOOOjCo0YBNcKyZRh0caGh5wCOO23e7LtuCMFw79CMEtWllMne7rnMjh0y0xKRGcOQC5C/215hDqGvsN9RwpFDh5iof9TAd7wKktJ5LI5GIQgQqSf61V@a5CeSap/v44Bv7UIno2VQqMKfoAhKEwhC50NQK2ZIFUyEiTeCzNIHBKMaN0u47qKFhBEy0EHRBwN2581JLkphacqn/pSh91b1B8Vfu7BprgQ1nLTCESHbw5Omjgyf7j3e/OB0b2ezCdyZVzAHhIL4m6EJaj9MNS@sWL5qYLAQXgbIxwuIFUmACDRS/O3zijUBwa@hF4wis4Bo@/hP7qttzop5yPTEX6Kq@clqchR5j4eNeRUBoaLf72BgZ8WEzrM@Rf3rj8dArJZNQynuTpgaN1uSrlts3u0kKBxVDv5/UselycIj9Gt6yEICMN7N4CN6nBarDjDoOzf7AhcYLDcWhaGAxDp46q/p2twdtYRyvs0aKFnAwpSbZhhYCtJWTQdpIANMX0Fa8/XySOWt/RTcKnK/1lJFJyr63heIPfjc6FjSdYlBbASmUa5/s9M7pHTYDKY2QrgOJMG1LDNlgXdBnoEhSZym2833ikLTAblKUFUSj1xPsxAUplcymMnk9l01CswyaaaCzqtjVpg7Mcaunjl0V4Kluh/oNQlzY8Vqm09G2hMFHFvS@TyCp6dqL01OnDgr66R3CDQfCarN6Ta8rZXYzyJbwr5SBexeSh7zrWwDvkhFYk95shTxrmzfFWduk0tVmyfFgKOocdcge74Ii9cYFed22wmUPAyTDjsmtBb9J9PwuuaRDqI9BJXwgpZJQoKCmBdZLIl4qKL2oHgLngNwKBWDz3gyeDj78HJIj2OhGvrfdqEd99ajXYCepNwQiUh9zC6W0h/2DY6gdA85HKQ2Zi0KaXVhR7D43Pd5JCYHEoKMfHtpqAQTqjA86op1gsBWYgEJR8xwkB/AV9pb25r2M2OgHToMICSfsfAANwqFBgy7IGQjME7LLE8JjIpvFJJ057oWD0JoWK6hNe8z7@N3JCAfz7HY4beA9bXA/AI0SF5LrNOrXtFq8l5UHplRAI9BkA2vgYlcCaFckCixKgslHDLEt6GFHNRSrlIoDJwBfZXf3QIq1LN5fpA6wEQUstc@i41FyV/1G0lTfADev0a0w8bvhAWzK9BOfANQTGYxgUy@J6AEl7cQdkKfn1N@Cjvd8dVcazsY9SDFwmGxW3KHlXG/z8RZhTCnTOGs0CgLfdmKX0Y2NjWgpWo0mwLQDpm007aApDqYdMqlkQn8amihEgkzoWqMQaFePXtV8yFOljjwwRc3hjT2MmbVSKV1PmDVdvA18K5AVQHnwreIL4ESVSgWNiiJXL3CoBvT3UNr3kHeOWyN7KEjwVVAI@LegQZqIAM171OZHVhnbpuspMqiMoNFooYoZG0VPa6nT@unlaTt@ehVNYGilbFagfQjCaxwbaN2ROxmC4lbLlFSQbUotXaqXm5VoKroVixXUPkRkKsonBSVuclrHohbwVOz0NAokFdSptXojgjdNGIoSEArw6NjQyuj3Y1HtsgDxN5W6Eo9CWCWaALFciUaBLi0kgkeJxh4BzkQP7CmQEgomVHHhMQUSkDQmhcX1G9awNxuFPQS9bqBlYw/6fDAeCgNJ8bCUfMPDhxW6hZa@r/dyf6DcYucd6kvDGZfuEsf0NLkwMcSvd8/VzsAdm8nPNWg0aaHqMroRTaoq1ITkwiFRsh/bHhZh07HciRfuaVzaAYqxg@1JbwLC0p81kwCusoeS1eq5LLp5F6CzYJgHqxIcsVL5uJcPoN3S4EYhiloJDpaAdkHTSWyQizjVhPfK6IQEFz1@33w2N3ytBbGVKQxLYUR213FHlgokgRASTf6gqUJSlYkZJQfU83VjXEK4UpWGDW/bAon4oO@aRFsurkPjQcNBKDy0zyHIkdWW@iA/OiAeNZ4XI6ud3JJocNYd9aCGgNSgJDaC3BoIh6TrDdvaeApBpRhWuGFH3roDpfOCtQ3DyLWynZLvhlwBxO5BJmGr1IEmru@k6uCoiEze591Cfhv9yeH9fd53QpUtVq/Yj9YYuO0J6JWi3XRkOd0E2wd@sh13YAMZ/PBvzvpHrjvmrXz4WNUzwxvN9mDSN6nP53q3zNpwLbfp9qkraF3Quf/JyDP7Ju@E8l13P38Muv6zk@OKVgp5Sprng7VxYz/k8mg5PQ/CY440zOoPD3mcMeXNrIz1lj8ZDcWMcMihw0RMRYM88u3zaO8XKRxDEfYFtB/gNDTQlUUvAn0GlsJjkTzi1DSc0SMsL/XUFdqvbIMF/nTyxxXHObaXukH25@NOZ8E6TdZnKoqm/tw6Q9Z8itpCGzGMUpZ7wvlqC37CgHLkJ5i2dt2fEF7BFIOe1fdHEI9AMcFRMqjb@6g@QdsENXE@d8wCRXqIgyEkoXGIjbVA1/RudFtAmRqq3LcU2aByAnVYEjUXaTPJRBd3mUqK44qhSY9LTxea9tR7sl3lA9bYdBrxVluSd75vNgDEdrXszyZa5Q1jikYDbwSVcIMQlEwatr@R1GAShkd96hIFKUteEloNUyOlnk7z@/WkR0ToMPn0dPpJyvgCGh8452vzTrJrlTG6ldSib94P3eqB2GDx6SLJIB8mTsftt1U@6AX5z3hzCTNCTDUIZp2RwAcbe@RPOLNxEouYGAjiMjRX7Qbca1lXvekhNLstAASl4ZK9PUucv2U1qMHONW/Yt8d1dqWN3UYPEz@ejJzr8@C4SjkamTNPEjNVKmz36NPPa6k6hyANTBzIKvDcmvrTKEEPBr0HZ6uCCefbjO0xVew0scDG9OoaIDWlMQ9AH2DwCMosiEikCFF/a72dp6VjQcMzZiHm3myQYJZypXX65nhsOZy3@GjianLzYR8RTYWi3xFjCCWWooEWUDRtdAMUy@z45P7@0ZEGHOrFovs4IFOCYme2eqBvrEq0T8lw4kvsk3aUfYJhFGyFS1CkoDHREOGBecvA3NCcgNhRFHStUQwsFRxLaYE1DV9RQK5wCQLhrKnWmGgUAItZCqSJgJWW4v/M4S0ngWeJRVmcKAnkjt0pAW1tRZs49mvNg3qD1FDwEuVtT5oiW9mMkfja1BXin5E9wLFgaDKRFghpqNXYBkg38i2zyjv2opZSi/X4JqvXy3yEHwKiTk9TbsX0TVPQkw@HkYAUOB@IVlnn2iRePwbqucVQHD8deFYSfAvIjibN2c1SKm8ashIgq74BC@4oX0dyySRTjqI/tYlECM2EWpzRtDhfKpSsZ9TIvjY5HJLjIxCkB4chYzyVbKPCdEXxMeOAnpsjbDqX2FPX8@xmn2avdvo2nwkWVNYlQRgByadMOLoyFgyiG5ZnKGeYGfMpy3wisKAEuVNFAy0pTBlZxBR2icQkUhpIRfb2LVrIbNNgxAYyzhjm9L3y27QgHx@5gOwjMQM6rHOQ0BDTU1B0nEqy33hbHP9FF94wSJ5f03nVczkcjuuctnPm0ihSYGqkND2LemYQenDWvxmyY3s9eix4DXDgfo1V2HmDZoceSzzQYIoYpicL6qYXGjZkp5k8ohf12C@JeXFqykK0Taszcbo0polmpr6@xadaLJDnTrNpr/IKRMDZZv57iTeQlVjyDC2j6X7pwQ4eqBZBfvI20Tzp12c1sQW6QyU1hlDi/V@/2Qb638ydHtRX2J8ZGBqgKWBOqZ2VmSWC4gc9lmcs73af9G2TCEOm20C2zBEkyewHhuWgaWhfVUHfGOBAhchx4E18gC66hs045nyc0X8vj2TZUJ0Dcru1yu@1WV48KhpUguZim4jAdS7bokAkZHkmWFM@sBNquKPAvR0pfyoWI2bm@d6bjCf8CerwrZloD/FeVzaFz1TWbOoWNEjNpm2tyfKReTZpu@rwrBuoxbklfuepp5FlFbQSMcjcQOPy5PMEjuwuVPf@e5W3ef2avKDXbVzhORNvqDapbd/mX1QQBmtiGPX5c5UXW6xUCgyrqWb36fGBnCigA6OIORZJnMGqhohmXyNz32zOUBXqfTyXBfMVQOJUWvF4Kr1iwHo4XB0e26cUvlhcHnqqtTg9lvU8JPksWZX3zVGCxbzZW3IVqit7YPZVox0yrhTmy6Y73PAajJRSGOscx4nOl@bcnPpYIbUmfXM0N61h8Tke/uDEqn5uUW2Istxy@7aHBbq/Smr6c@7mceE8ZXqE5lXYyyjZhoYo1uNqYFouBdzWGOeirmCrD5BpfA4ozrQN8YnmriJWy73Ae6UG0YPGMH8ur9TeLMXqA@ST2m/1TajKV9YIC72O2Kt5C69e2J5Fj@WEPVuK6LjVX2q/WAr8/sRw/@BtnO3Zfddjx/RcR6DuCKjAn8t5OkxL23RU6mUPm9eIIX/yxDxDzX7X7ecK3aQJj5W5Phl1UPSL94cKuUBI6fotQsrXgFxHF@@Vov0sOTq7LYNo/dcIJ86GjGtq2WWSSgzqrE4dtA1wRHB5yh6kChRSS/I@xBUR41jOhTnz3z9H7bGKtH7tMZyRRg0KHgYoFsAwHnEt@@eJLbM@tvaHCaUbYPO3JSKUuWd9C@oret7IUmak9I8MoadSHy6iOv2JNbGWtjUOm68sXEa8pp3x4UilRDI2xRAAjjrgmpfA1xvROPwgrLGqxq@1wsSEVrt1uzazKNSGoIAPsfX8FAxP0XAzRNeZDBdydaGB5hytJ1lv6Bdpt72AHbp8rBwq3KIsLajonkX32kYTb@ThzLNKJpVKCR0mNJSz8LGuMZUOwr6y@XMhYrKZxzz3i8N3o5BxeRxElvDcxpUiyFjVtifPxWLSsR1rPMPnB0rTpuv2PyanQKi2bdTGQLmkObzrcuyGuiNWp7B574WHfR7Nzqp@C17biOYl0AfbzesyPTzW9EG5qeJo6gBHuhY/1/fghEaubosFl3NjtxCf1dtfrUuKDhFdK2j5taWOa6hu0@qb/DXNZdbBK2rptfAWhYYYBcZRYz5WPB/jj1wTSsMZEMtuQ0OlZw0s@lyj6JvtVxPPf630NHXxXuU8taxWcrpvtVZ5GNogFxx8LgxOh5SlsetAE2uMEwixqdLHKarCdpUE9ocTlxL5YGB2Lb5HxTpJOe@zwGk6vGU3Ny7vvSjxqTktCDbvYV7NElCozqyZ57@XAnw8a0G@Tga397hdK/wt7Ab9gNK@am7szSrW6bk9p2f1@IT04GtV4QB@HPM9RdahDlh3ezhHbjhcmDsfpmff7fc/hJ4oGrmgdN3OUpz2cVUtLgn7KLgzswkO4nVr/5055rIDDStLTc@aQL3kuWN3aKn0tcprH/t6@HOVDPVHv3/eTqS1TX2giP/@eeHf2rbsmu54OKRXY9ifePSgoCothr5Nb@rwOS8029IddbU37qCpCUtNTIihQfflIqZpj1s9XITOOdvqus1Wz74N6aZljh37LOn3@vDPD2q7ImVspt5Ha61vA3lHMw35pRJ2P8bXwapMFx1IvFoLDGv0lWWddLTeWx2aZy2Pd4iiiZWwTzhUGvmq8BItpy@9ntjjOdDQJKmgh5ePTKBhFe5iWsZKzYoWX8zFsJiusZJLSUlHhVy1UqDw6Cv7lxYm0IWKWDrNH6sQCqeSMApNePkYcotJRdRBaIe6bsF@gb8WZkMtreSc3qTr3RSYvMe@DSoaPlZ3W9Ak6VCvNdRZpiNeq8hs9JO4ehLeDdC5JtbaYZXs2nEV8qf3VdO14dWAF2TdZGUfWt8eevzJ1M7K0TgxSQra4teHDDltZssb0yJj2laHj4Kg6TYVceDSOC3oIGoLx/SxEx2FOVe8uOBy3C4IdbXP5p59v6vUlqXzj5Znf1Bnql88sbomTuJ@ZI9xFugSriCWXTZv6VbYX5uYnv21CaRsFbPhVhB8JHIU3jMAv5bAe2x27dbDhYwIkBQEFlNI@WuB/dHqZl5c9GwP51AFhjUdU8hynImR6xrQblji83rXfbALxrwA8fWVS30v6153hzNchjYj07qedXtMvazivarpuGp22VokLiaD4cQTr@U40CytcC/04IzsvQsbgKuvQbSyntkfL@@pDnW5ghYmKsW5cZU2/g2773bZNwopBkobKGGonC9hnHtQPT/FqUEjZwknUtwfOPKJHR3qiCfsNeStlWaq7djj9b054zFOE/LfmBhec@DSh@QjfGp3PxaCerKcIo9u1/Xna55vqd@B847dyahloTHYyCTcLBCxWnv@tGZcKuLiRiwX4Vba2tEbqA5dZzJWRxNnba2QW1srlNi0kAuxAYt9bf/xMyXMDTQN/DYt1ILG38Trz@amlXMGrjGZ7YAitlqOLvr22xL3@b5LRzQH@ZYwu7g5VIvE9X13WXvn6WxkjT@4wQTCfzK4b7Vw5PDWuJ@4j13HhdpoCIJycGTxzQQW5nosD4jBHuFyeaBP@9ZojgnsikqIaxvm0GpC/vbnpg@pizjg@@bYXFEVUd8gtf8C0628Yveb1ugVdfqFzKuatIsIPbSm1LZYzTC8DKrjVourxNgft1BGFkZsvKHrOvxJ0jYFL/3xeqkCVQE9PnysXMMZ/gv9AkvbZ4tJPTznE0WsNt/tYlVaR1bT7fPnmmlJjs2nBZgj2/KSj3DzBLLLZZgK2pe3Vobk18qQedMINNlz06Nx@uVNjTlIffoRs4B65qjl4kiYMKyZoBPa8eAWMR0sGuBzB5pA@ClILLM1EXsv3oZWf9Ac0GNlgyGUm0dWE5cbNWmbkLE5vZmZvGdI7JEQmtQV7Czgiyss1DkWewqtEeX2amuhHbVIVXtID5LUK4fLab6O6thW642JvWYu0WveN73gDmlOPiHjir7qUDGiXuSkSUvol5akxdlroND0LXXcG0GbPzle173t79@yZDxkMrBwkHlxFGal6up6PUqsu3w8PRCuI0sVeweCLAn2EeT6obq7UvNE8PA/vPfVJFTCjVzG39MERNftI/iA/GTkiNeHcOBT1xt37Okh4I3rDlaJE0xWFoLAi5cMNG2tSgTknjPp896Hbmjq1aBNzTGV9q9V1T6J67GlWs65SjvMTW@myOWryZK7uBnq2GqrYoMFHGlQH/kLywJv4r1kADUsG3G@p57khJ3mMmIG6DLiXviSAfQtd6wOPXonh97Tg0eHJ9rQ05fWT7s9XI9xQ49b2LHBKKRCXVKvzFFovJPPSGvb3jh571hX9x4daOhhBb35iIYKLxyZW3it7PcUW4@aSXNlKwhdrfFyBfHhyeNH8fnaTxbb643cgaWEnfeOjxO4tuWrx0udw6EfQOnouNOVwQ/2dV1Zwr7PHBodXCU9l8S0CtKJBa1RYMaHfMOXW5Wrlju02iezofU5VJ4owb0PjD63MpFPzHO7i6WQFVcSigoqK2q5jBKanA2NbWsUvFfl55k9RGnZoleSv1ZOR0HNIZ0cpZdrD@tG/K9rMSwlZiJ8XCA9dZNbx7YKJaPbQ1PS9P6@iOm6vorOx2YH8pVlV2bWoodl48N99/wDhpIt0XhRAyt1DFyl2rdOJc@rAxDdSXxg97ywBGNz5TSYdQAC69zSAn9hOTPTUWksa516UYLQOKltrZdvWB8wIBXM8DnHDaGXjvEFs@pZrEVG5ZaIT0ahIHt79w5uC3AkaLne16dPnrGnpoe7m6z3GMbY@gCM55rRKxX7rXBrvZXDqe0RgDLWwusOl5fnEjs2R23XmU1vH4Sjxa1YtdNmxQEs/CJPVt@e2svqqhbv13q6fJrRbXHzdRzubEEPDu96IwC9/86/0PVUivY0wree4p@35IxfwFkMTeYMN8oLO50cBKKhhXqLBhbK0tboI2uK01F4b/CyRv3S@i23pu7LK6urk3VuBXLj64GOJk54h1ovIfYY4Mv4@MIqT/O3EY7FnHhcURZ3qg8vI@MLqHAfM772Cfy@fcs2xBIncAhWfYmFVbjdEehbFi5HlAgErneLOZWKni2yHdwvvgTSVKEYwarEd5XxI6uxzUuxYKlU0q9w0ZZckplYUBZsEsk3OgTAuEUbJIqpZzrbHIPLpr/cidFW3ewtIxUN6gQ9m4IvLRlef1oW68AAp83LpwdP949Pdk@eHddS9StZEasdOW6OA7H562A/SbdlSLygG2Q93/aU1kv2ITraRhxVO89PF4OUXUtaZSFp80TJOxhm89Jxkkla9pdUrwA/VeaxkSvIcbTisP0UUwaJVZslvlquTySVNzlomeKETCux1LKIh6bnQbKE@/WDDMiVpdPoyiMWO1VCgeu6blvE6Fns9suP8cHuwaNnR/vMR3DONRd2e9yrFLN8I1MUj6oF@dSxaQZBhUVFkCjkVaUSfRAFwkS1KCvRYkvaRBQYHbz51MFlmiL0FottEnygYDTIlOR//WbyKqrhZDgF/EZ9pKJMUB49sBNcQPVnP27zTbb9bRP80zpGA5IFtDxdEosjVyyNRIpSyRyuPrODNrWmVZDBbtrzc1Ak2mMduPKCdjy6thuOQhtU8ANYxGZFfkTEIP7GvNirghsPQZPw3MYlkByHDu4DtMjKOBBLe19pbBcPJAGeZyZt9A6oT5wx32tDrMyPAB9pgURJsE1Clm8LL4c8Rrc3gJWbVtd2mOeAqmqNS@wV8Bn2XJT4OlxVrUZvBPFB85No1N540A95vLFxkJc8HSff/8p3k90yA/M0dQ@@fkl8dcD8y9z8Iol5fXNzoXn8YSRwQzCBNY88oDnSO3T2isPXO8@JhXsg@aKS2QPImnOiNHrnMfCnChJ2DidW@xwyClgMckmsc@bxWaN6DHckKyWTyEY4CqTR3E5ryidaXNuZLJfNZfQkIKme@wBpK@EuLiLjABWlBIwvndvDyssmsNf2NpNR87EquTLPzeSm8yItvwwQ3QS/0kUPkasxCANB5iHArSqCQX0S1xUMivIoqkdRFLVdqGjIHSsk/HYEIWQWA2JxGlm4N@0UD@EZj2b@DntNPNgmtM38pgCk6lDNkEmRJbE094k7BpZZWJTMl@biRCNeqeHWVR4/ZIo2tkMe1G6WpvmKMn8/e1G@NCz3HFQ6db1@DOet/BxBHCOIkryMZWsv2On41KknOW8yYNMfCpYNM7MD5n@W7K7gWZ7u3ZvbmsWub0qGxGJ3jx0XVbwHkBgWM5JGOqnnlHmSMpmlSRIpEtFAcnCzhbcQHYgmEBMty37lDr3dvf2Drx4@Pb6xdRf5jF73BpK8uh0/VbVErR4YouFkLWbJvQfJ48f3HvgZMUc6F5LAoL6IlOjrUjJvuSHI@Uzg60lbhuH11K3G@DlfLngd37SxDjUKdAMPPfUR8dJsPPUBzam/HrlRWEatbHYdSnN4yRDoPb4g6gaqMeXyqlbfrp46kehNTlhSEF5EtC0sBGA69bY2k8jsNxOHCQsOgzvBY2y8cFlMLy@L8mYad5DBJZlj92y@d46wCDmE0utHAyJS0pK@15Wl75Cr3fMdngx@WB3faya8w0YI4VxqHcVDoE78c@9Qisz3pxNbs/Wg/dS3m5K/swnfos3fSSrYnY3vShJTJLHLOY84Jk7Cm5amGg29xxSUdgQrwdbt9ubDUyQo0KivPZ1AO@6pO@S73tIQy33LNx25IH7vT/hYrcW@OhmAvw69jizq7gLJrUJgoGQ0QJXrTyAlxGZv0zhupwfx1XDLN5FwbdDOxqaK1rOmbbsLsj2mJECifaLrdRZsCIeJpg3gnKhMeTbPhbVF8VNc5hYm@0ftCjidI2DWTM122tY0Fr2IKqU6xI/20Yvn51FFXsZLtDuh2K6vfX2bwgD9vL5ekphjUTr9PQCXSYti8aaUALvrgPn@Ov6RG8Wi1vMkOjmpgrr48Xj0CIygRsQ6A3PIYhOH70GkMfqMncacBG3aolb5NmYOi8epiQQvctAYheyQidffMdOZsViyAkyAtp7Txtcbe8hquqbVwUyRKGwTj8LZA40L9/NQJGjWQpASga0gC0HDATDihUTjDA5h0F3CbVZGtJPTEmc6GYR6BVykCaWaVe@w0IlGi5qjXCyWRIYuSsUiA@67KQ61JIC9Ied8XR6oK/YLAJpBg1aTInNBflPiRSjeCEfkodhoANCJhLYe9PcfYABrvjFgqzfCO7bvQFnBLVNKz04eNApKUmbBhgXdkd3GXiu@e27QaBPnHUAxTS54jZZ5G@1TDIY7UTX4jgi4UdIDKjDyNZEaCZPh@vmec97U9bVcLwKKXACfGawAxKqOhg8Ot1zzxw@XuC0X9j/7GZ4gKsc2d3LpRv88Hs2myvDQy1mWZZ9snqrqZs3Ipip3N@umOT6VmZnMbN0/t3qd5kE3eSrLLM0yyeSWkXt9NtRzWy9q2utpXa4VKomz@tMz9vTpF@8a7xR5ej6TT2MsH2F7h29lHRIQKeVZkeG99KKj/ZZea1rpchTgnp7iyaByXk4ma9E6/MnpJVzcU62qVbWd@rt3Si0PaZrOTiN44B47vLsILGYYyrFt20l2OvTabbjdHqvzI2Mj/IrHYyoTFmqN27HBtEN2012r253smzNub0cm@HowFmEff@P58@doeE4Xe3MkwnPozI@j1DCzEWakjD/7ycZV4vJpY/vPvjVIWhv4OsTXd68eo/lYz36ysfHJvXuZTAKoxM1Pv/H067u7u5n7iezTWnYno6Y2tv/0TzY2DGPbSG7UPU@vR2tnZ1/IRioja3/2o2jj6dOveR5mC15ppoMRnwW4ddSpztgbuM46DP9kftMOmU00NztvmBF5EwG2jszo14gwXgorpCWFrw2mV3fy/@37h68j40jVSD4fwXsceR3JFSLcCAb4Svtf55FqZBu95a4is2SlUgFj/r/9ewhf/SrAQZfZNjyqWR9WbhapqhUK8jZSzYFBNwyI9//65jdv6fa5y2pwyZm8Ie/U4dqia1vCbaLUVDJ5zbteuKPfYcwZ98aWiy@bvxx4MbPsQKv7qBaPx@uaCpfWoEBJXTdOqcMmzFrU3xIJrMuM27CQ3ZxPhA24PY8QTwFTEV9xs7AgVuMWz6/7e77kKj//x76OpEhu4651v1oFUWhUja1qnK6N01KJkz/J8gXZde9ij1b0VI6yl@yRIHZVThUMOZFI3G3gecxsijRVp5E5ARmnEYssUDbC5l8sbBVhfjA29/Ox/vbx@vP/7c9/8Offp98P6P5PuKOW07Y7yS2O/HmVX6xalasj@fKUPu6yVKlQKiQb7Oo0tlWr1o@Ynvr0bTSbjh5jGskTO1X8Hs5IcFWr@PDRwK9qhNtUuWluJ1yqwQf5mAdZ7o8JyeQTNQJVsJh4pNbO6xw3jl/4muLFanchm2QjX5TrVSNrHELW6TJlXJH1Nj3mRkSKduDagB/94drBzmNhg88NsuQu5HXJtRGgcvu1gKsUqdWSdasOiiyr@kDubpQ2CqVcyYBMWQ24vAp05DwsTbS8VtAMEB/vahvsiPN6ncX96zR@6/VM0xrCSAYXb1V1pxEp8o9wVSUWuYSr/m6r9g5YV0RdE@U0vq3Wq3GBEby0xt16XL26qmkv4uWy@G9XA2OZLm6ChNSvVHX7BcCq3YTKgdJTa7zYBrDx7dp2xd2jW2sgidX6i2ptezGsCH73bhxl7F0AUN2ss2jGjebcu0yJxzdVdaO2Mg0AuB5j0CqADLzavqpe1bavrra34b9NzyvxBtur7Rt/es2vFX7m7lRsTmvJ6mnyVLBNHb61ZBVttOQpGKrwBn9QDUkRFQqUFNliW5Eh0/NpMDGrpG8Z6WR2@kluH1SjWl3FFkxFrem5bF3lkuqlxkoq34ZbL@QUDUVRw@00cOWcxl5KkZfvv/xf8D59/@XvY70PxbIoRZJb2Dwo8lYCPB477PHjx3g/dhz4w/2YXw7aoMVjtHP4w@E@fD@BNbfB4gBCgclGISc34vrMYJFtOZdHsfALN65oNPpPXhrFfJS3oHGF2UsPLH9h2fVPfmHVJUXeFrGctzzG0yRFqNxDXkD5qaLxEh/N1/h79AZ/r8f4O2nh7@g1/tjJG/wdjfH3uIm/px7@Tl7jb7eJv5MB/u69xt/jMf6edfEnRSqgbG/upPqpVko/08/AYLPUiKV6qZ7expZAymKpWWrGUgNXb4PJgl8KTHaqw1JdlnJSjq6DIxjGLDVGUwdeXfh1AMoIfjaOMZ/pqRaDWPoAlJ@kQ@@3IMiUU6kGTUj5pQVqsaZrKS1n13H/8ZpcN4oFpiGFtUbt5Wm0jhtbGsUMa86sjdOXLOKBSl2OJE9Pk7xzgBmZMm5VfnXVaOw/ud9oJFEUnT52D@f/w8NB@HPtf3DoPj50By78Dw8PHzOrGr8bV@/CVanGt8VrJ1It75yWVCy3vqiIJLd3TqtpFc25OJR@A@3iH3nNIcK7unEqRRloKhdl0ofKF@flizIZgk8wNMqBB@GNG8CyLPQosCn7CtUFXOcXZIkPNF48Pw1M3JB8fnGK7QJo8AV/UDjDn/8Af/v/Xf/Hz1isVgf9JnZ5tR2jS8GfolxeXV6JZ1WJxcRHbBt@aAHfGOTyqopG8nQJplpMqStXV9wOnjFlmwOsYhzbVQo89wiFPxLESfHyR@wf9o1xi@sUt8A25yP1p6fTVEopN/0td3GUynxLA6ZKmQ5Q2WzW9Pqf/og2Vt5RyFM2Uy7rW4x/GBmjXM74X/lCuVzwPzZjseLNq5ra0XOg4GQyilIuw8eODzYFnwHYAoD1P7IA1fLMFpX7cuTy4JC2HAYxkY0omCIuGGIp2pkcD7mIyiX5zp2YODxzZ1e5c8copt6@DWyGQ7DSF6wajbY9ajTQPv32rdyQaeS8mIXvVOHtW5BlUcUdxZ7g2SgQUUzV2SdGleIsuiMgRB6cmZ405lj0TM8cj0exN/YwIeNsGU9W6OiCVModnUZ/@r1vfes0WqnIqky2GR0BYCwsu72dy1SruQyYcwWglLx5yU/x6MaLunK1mZQ5NZi8GY0IJ72QV7hsjKI71HBspwoF3MOLXV5FKNtZJqvEQLoqoGhdRfDHrfVikduzTC5WiBfFr7KhsCroAPyH7dN0PLOV37pbZ/SbLrtQJJcvrYp@Vbm0StjNd1VuiYPpcHmddedOugg0LaTKp1KjcX/3ZLfRqMiyjNUhPNCShLuE5@EMR9EaZXi2WK9h@uqn0WipfJeYQy9kWSRaFv7UKNQSrFAkMkh2B9fOQtolXTT@NySD3viQRF/QBlji2fFsfj99tLu3f5IwtkGlMR7s7iWM42f3Ijp@Zuff5JzG76P93fuHzyDA00f7u8f7nx58vv/sKdh77GJ@@RJYPOfvsGnJ9wV7Lr0avTEty7QmltW4mEwuXrNXtt2wgbD9iW3bbnfEPKthWdYQvPlXGe6W7ZmvXpmjIV3s/Q@/8/6H/9373/ne@9/5zvvf@cFPv/zBd@D@Mdzf4@/v/btiFp8//fJf/O773/4dsPxPcP8R3D/56Ze//k1@0/cfw/1fQnZ/LO6QP35LAOuXfvrl93/00y9/@Tfg/lfi/o2b96/8ZPn9g2@vvjHc9393vZ/v/Xu4f4/D8v1@77e5Hb5v@P9t7u@Xf@P9r/0H/v9T8UPj77z/tT/Gh/j457/xp//l/bf@o2EU/vTfvv/2999/@1vvv/3d99/@p8b7X/@3eir8@N33P/iDv/rD3/urP/yf6P9jev7eh/zf/8Y//4v/9S/@97/4Q3H/BO7/AKaf/MV/BIb92z/4If6//wd/@0c/xP///K//9g9@9W9/6d@Q4Te54f/@V/@OP//6V/7z3/zWd//qJ9/8m1/9yd/85h/81f/xy//nr//nv/7vf/@v/8dvoeVv/uSv/uiX/vJb3/nLb//Lv/zWlyue31n7/PID7L/8R7D5cDw/BM6HpOtjbb78ufD5@1BjHgvwCXD3P3v/678IDP5rjL3/zo9xkijcK/4/NnTy82P@9f8Bg3EzzeiSAhPcv/r@O99DEv0PQCL4B/T6bvCx4MI/vjv/ALL@1rVAEau0WHkWjEJ8C1oYW8WiqEAD520K@dMv/@WPgih@cRHqghvE@F2UVAtu30UZ9/6H33z/o3/6/oe/@f6Hv4S1mZopJnYTqr6@8xmqQDX7Af7QY@5D/IHHL76A@Kdx6ipV4/jFvhCOX3zxhTR9m8RZyXffgu0XZMUvxp3AjQkn303Y40zVsB9uTPnGTbR@G44ayRDHaOOkCmz5eko2zaZxv/MQe@J4JyJ6mm7x/kR8ki06TyV8zP9z41RicfTDLzzIxTeSQYQTUXCjlIVo4tNpqPeS1A/CkNvQKBLFmykyTMF0Gp9CixQMEEMcnO7FWaVSiWPACscHPjlq1QIjVOLxCqQbQ/MwiUYBQUzvERQIWYkfscZWZcoDxhFe1SdHXEKrI1k35Hihch8irEzvM4SFwAnsy5eVaqEyrSK4d5we8Wn8HuGEwCrxafUdfFcIZhw7le6/A1QKlXi8WsAIMZE8exINnklZShylPc7iIg/gTT20dxn7RNYLMh/R2ECCcd/4jM9979AY2w64n8a3RHLo7xvp3iKCb1BUIhbG3XdIVdzh2iN6ALiqqmkag1tVEZu74DzloOIULbziHEKcOII4ILAANsS8iFP@xukD4o9Utj76ilclnprNzU0pUpXT8iGN8MSh1T46K/GTON7yplGJybmijNYWzfzmqbM2n1K3w9b9LXjq8N/foAnZcVYmtDaj2LkXZTw@9kmc33fvbrFPIPX0nttJTI2n3Qx2rmNCt@Nx2YBYq25cegHSTQL2JUBvJW1aoXGluJRIMKZVIujGDg8PBWpk8aIixYH7jbSO3zgQMJlMIhBC0xJaIiHeGr3JQhMGjVzFW9tEmlNnJDOMTBnaN2WGVizcHNGh3YqW7969g8yiSRmlA2hRMjE/w8gUyBEs@GLNfn/mLxwwMkWJN6eZnuNnZcfoKD2FKRKLsS1F4tN3ORLBcG/UKBSiaFIgT7TYlj9dJ6dLfh8hdREGIXgbr5BVfMe9Q7Z3@Pjx/pOTYb3OJIvOOLQaw5HbsjxvnWCOYbjdJ/f57H6jmEM0IrUaxnxSMlAsSfulFAnNg/tHB8clxmkicigWQFLK1P8rSFHUpchw@Hw7IqY0yHjohisf47M0T3/MKKYxwmpZirQsbJYAw@GflaXHXveeO4W2fEKWE3oOm2gK9aAy6etuqVR5p2fyErzpe8Jweyi@lhRKJ84B17a3iWhS9VKlXm80QgbnpGpVzA1iulQ93j@BACeHTDdSGoOW/mUmb2SymayRzuWyeUPP5IqZXLaQhroml8oahl7MZIqFYv5Kqn7BphriqoK5X@lbTnfc28QZOfJpSg7RY7OWSuDPSKfhCRATejZf39joX6qI4CmxxSVOrbqCz0sVKfAVuJj0FYl9BazggjhwvhQTk9UODstixhDu2hDj04ZkPQuFW5FOgZE4OGkYvsrDIZQfaO2Hbimy8Y1vjFm1Cq1s9eCBFAEx1WP@tBnVbms9jRipPRlZ5NplrG1/buNZLFrb9oZ9cwaFM6VJkaurqw5AOniAY6r0yUO08XnVIpsmmK@mpvT/X3@fa3tYBYbcTg6r0rYJxsx20gRjE4zZ7WQTagRpm@9uxHDxZEUeW1PcTI3byVXP6nc0XApQkQmUIW@L3QKrIlwV11S4ZruCK@xwLnxMuZTalbbbopOepLbWdNszzcYzMnGlVUUysvl4Teeczn96IWEksok2zqkfmmNcM7GTTZUubKftXmhfPH70cDweHlk0234nUywV6rWaLMdrdW3oDut4AhwvU@rGBrChZbZVeHdcZ@ypRqEuXQU4A0G88axvVaWtOKKVwOReCuYsOa5jXW1dxltu3x2VOp3OlWQmmpcq/wZtsTx0PdqIuGQ2oSoA2Vkeu8NS6kpqXs49qWinFsG2ZHZA9l@2@CS5kmxkC3K5Vp5/53NyuX4l3R1YbdvEGfOnqcsbgXIp@Srwc5pCb0s85dATJJQnD3Kb79JUpaldNRBG9X2oY2r1bX//Jsx7w1CNtJrWVT2N/1sMBv4/3L8BfwOfECptSCe4hvEJyCQQug57hNtFj1124rp0Mtg9q7XCx17PpDlseyPX8/4efu6Zzhl3um/zjYMCp4cmHgngDexxb4WPZ8MBLn@0Rv9oEPYHTUCQigx5uAePUd91l3nIs2dPV6TycbBVHxCD79UH3o8OPn14Enqf7O/uPZRy7N7hk/vXXlnhKcse7T84CT7z3NUPmg1AfH3/0aPrn@IVweoZu1k3WDbvG3QJJ8HegcbJHWHM5ubGFBqf8/VZthdMyuQL8UrSib9oy2RYopsWa/EVqdhaot0ihNKk54uSNGSOe8HyKdZ2@30TT0XsbIBlz8TFKBaqAX06vBOjvnBH/faF3bY2pMe47qWo49FviIT0EIAMJi1amm2PJdx7qI3nFWK3fhOPXJ/gmaArLOGFVmgc2d0eiNkL1/cgNU2Twf2xF4S3wtd4vcWYx0F2N1z6N71LEQm1PXNsRgrlO3f0pyPg7GohVSp1LWgPgAys7k@Bu9iEPQN@N0coSTeTbDMr51ryA6Y1IuYWaFhdu8a8@vCIFbCzuWWmM1ug8OqoM4CWZ1r5CEpf0HFYooBqaM0AVec0lTTbGReUEnkkO@U3rFUeVr3UlXU17livabOqXJ5k905GYuXSX//Wj5HFt5IgzSK6LONs3Q1d0ki7NIqFbKGYNgqJQrGQyeq5bDahGwlQ3vNFqHVSekHPFbJFPVHIFNMZUNfANVvMSxE@FSq5RSDhXQKwTgsPM9smBVXrVaUIHwZib2KmwiJm8D1hsgVhZDy@2hvTcsAtuyIbGaanGLRNAKLJWizy4MFe6sEDWb6HHzj4vZeS5TZ@ZAupVP6eLFvkslfAald2eZgC7gkhj/lHKnVvT5YnHABupyjLPfzYz2HXhizb@LG3@@ABxtPBDwPDg7cz7sI/@v5HHrw5@JFOU9@ILL8OwIG/XR5RhjDdxw@ME10ecJc9cJPlT318UimAcMT9cQgP/bTu7sryAf/Y3UWXPUp4lqP6GX7s0iXLwDpYfGS5C4buCAquLDfBiIVIlltgas1MsMOj43DPPWdsyvKMEwhJJMtT8m22zmRo/wt7jObhw4dmb9y2uvyajfi7BaiBiz2d7D9ofvpps9ttjma7@58eocve3kOzM5uMmt2mCNZswOVCGHA5G8yuX4DjQaNh9pe6fAYuzjWXxqxhIW4N8zXgJK4uRjJo7IHLHrgsG0Hj0OAagNcmXvcG8L5nNsnFv8iF3tNmUy4jo6LmR@e/Qpmho1gTA7M1csv4Pa1sMBaNRROzWi5VL5MDG4COlypf0cGvMXya2JZWLme1aSVVr0wreYNPvejE5NOpkbXlxMZgRy9mSxvmjm5k4tMSLgp2O1EWVfUdFtPvbL1hsSfKjpHOlOTTnR1Vrun1HUMvlHL5F1sTWVZK@NxJ50vgMRWFliY@lFq@vpPPhoLk83EzaZTyeaV8BeQYQyXbROHSiMUuLPNMURBdbBFBEvixszNKp13uxKaJaYXjxWZKeVrRy3w7KJa6AauNew9OWmN3xCF2Adx0J1Wig21lvViQIf5kMqYoIJlIiMB7PrHq@ddOzk5OvgCZBW1N0VJ7yk9LLIvPTx/uadB4E1@4Z6D2ADVsd6TtoWBZcOFb2vlWJyBWtYdQU4IS7tvhQo2R29f2p9B@RhXWd/B3gtLE/j3aycMFOMfQTOUx4zrXMm0C4bQshlsq2m1mVqpgMtssRlgxU7mgOrpRrVYalQE/m7YahPqMkQifgznwOO7B6lsKfomLF4RDo5K6Kjcr08gU4DQqTNVfDtz2SyPeKrdxJ8V7lXsYuNyAd7NsVSw8oVeOyOXOjgON/onjmR3rqTXCteQHh5tQEeGKhliHWcomO6XzfPdQpb5SqyPmzDF7MhnETLXaVBatQp9ImtjX/CRf0hIbHJO@KncqLPZCKb@Gz9Emi7W1e8pOptyO3WMNBWxSLzsvO8xguUyZjjiLISQoREQbOidXqVQ/AyWHAz4rlQARkcdnABNjArB2mxxMZWhflVuVPoupbMoUIk@m3K3UMPRbfGyrslxX1drbulRV1edSFcppeRYxK96kSdvvslRTN1K58hTs9Hym3IOMNV9My6PKEJrz5T58im4LvpLILAM5gWoA5s3b2Ptf/KayrWYr3K5MoN72Qa9oaI3KtOzghh7AEpV0BRzitUwqkS1Asy@bT0CFbIAGkEukE5mEmkdbqI2hLQiWOqgDsX5MZkxOpKYpTU/olp6A0v/Sbr9kSuIsBioJkQw@xu4@Hg8MNpBJyJX0CW@TKXFjq88gF1xmbqvEpiApypgwoHmPDe1ED0EdWWafQiiKytJbsf5mDP1snkyG@7V6qbQ/HX4NnGLq651cPJ@Kv1GUcmxDqXjWa6lalqooVSjVww3gWdGjw7zJoAZ5PN7U80apVmtiCvOpRDqVhuTZjbfdbbkq1xOpjZwOOXTFSI9hXGBwXWaujcztGqhY41nbTC8aZUmjyQsUox4ziquWoCgSTpsTAKWhEHZIYRY7lf21dLFoNG9Eo0q0jH2/G7LosgMJx4/tBlEbvaPvyKA/ySW5aKCHuaCk5VKpsAp1JWEDm2WKUuRSurq82oaWZ5JmsYGmyDbIpGrVu1KkxBjocadiQ47kBmMfOzkuvl19wd@nOH0W4Eq0IVeN1WnKimVjc4l9jktDd1gUEDNHg5phpOs1Iw/1G8hM36th6GXs2Y7gPF2tCpT3LgG/7XgVV1V8xmYzM676lL3DWDe@KVGiI9fJvlvZ7R7tlv2vPexbO5VkWS5H5chlNBK9gp8UuUtLOQy@lINFQos5@PTPlgX0eRchicH2Lv3@lhIeCxEzS1w@1OrKuyd2/7KQVnnTHwTW1VVkM0k5ImbElz97aWQhjxzXnyIPTSBUxqHqymaxZzCSfDn0vmEU0o8PDp37owcW4zPkC5mGXI2wlK7ihPNySdhm@QxZuVgwZOMsEWF3I@UIO1Ojeolm0bPhcfFF/kXhxeNnh88OH0iR0423Gy72GjOfLOyd89WvgcdoOhNl7LQSmVYyZTFLqVpV9W0D97rJMzx7vaPn1NTbKmffKjnkDHB5/4u/kZluF@DbAO21BFmYjRvVqr5lMCUyfP/l7@MeB5f7n@8@YlHPnLG/@5MfGfm/@5N/TXN/oldlj3oo8xHwiUY9l49cXg4vL6/g4m7ZSD3CkcrkFTDz7nA9Mp@oX0qa5lY@njHuOuWk8KvndSXiqRHR6Z/PRry3wslIFcDJ75UnKzmHWRDZP7Kzhn53G5lCD9b3sPngr@UVgSsKj1@@ZQw@WtV2t2sbZEomWemdyrbfqdvsHfZqv1M32MtKFUdidVwV5HfjblWrVYTCotV4civKjCy41a7K9TijnmBoD76wtpyt00WOPt1gxaID9pa3JcYNTrc8aPRtOfSztjwPPv0va@uVx2Qc2Ugm223a/GXbYtkq5P9WEtA5Vd7/4q8bRu7v/uRX3jbeNr4woOVWLOZ0I/Iz/Wc/Aw9rlqP7zS7q5cZ142gImmtsxTnBWgtainh4dIdx/37jDZtrqDPYXQea7PglnaOeQ1nT4HsctWPkbQtXqyZIa6YdSJSyJAXaJWnFo24rQTDYFu7hDmVTupS@gk5QmbIKiEvpK3NQYDGA6tNtNbz@ZDSk2e8xCqfXE@wOBIEYvoL7R23QKlshc1UQU8mtm0E5yh5RjXQiNrA8D3ejglpE@goEEftt4dG0Ji4IR5@2A0JeQy@EJzm0axB3HeLu8wANso1R6rmHBOPY8UAOaM7SV0AZICrYoCMwexs8lEGwfAUIAGmICcB2nW2ztMIu7Xi8PN/q6gpnEuOeY6a/GFXCYAitjYuf/cBl9AdWoLHjCS/IFyKHQT0LWfpAOAw@0lkBnR@D0xcqXbRa/INBASzamSVGSWN37syxqlTstsIoRQj/zB5ixxTlg7McVwDmt5c@aZfkBMNNxMq@bcB2QPE4oQtcp/Ldw8qhoEzGzytJgv8HMy1y5LWsIocyJkDkFy8VLSAZBEay8zxsse0K0428wgLkW4B7i5CifauCRuDp9BPN@MJ3vAIMfxbx908G6XMS7uwTfHt9NTKDam@Cm9finjRcGIhVxHzXGZRiB2M/dBAKkmL3yXfHHkEDhUZa/S2sYmldwWDzLb8ID5obbGQYTtLNKviiUOibwdvEzZpEPBu04UTLhQz1hq5DuzvRThQ4/xk4AmSU2CSHoz1xLnCzc5E3FDiMkUcb5CDnI8a0WxWdEkdhceiyOYJWrE@bBLO6GmsN2swoshgxGm3m4wTgFApECDdB20UaN/vWAFA6tiyGGxx5pWSyC1rRpEk7Gj22ga96D2yoShwvKQ7kS17YZ3byBDdrVd0OqNBifXgEFSksfnyUVOwe1HfdM9a3zyzehxtbWF3vMdD3QWlNAGXnNxC2hN3FRjrBUuCc4L7gzsMrz42FRCjsRmym3Hyn9Y1YA3P0LdVJ9ggP2zs3nRB96XoriSauN/P8/Tlolwn41gKRa4mV@ZUoLgoOtpyQxE4jFdrkQsN@/GEMGpz@Dh1oBF3cOmfYWJWwjgGh2fLXumMphtR@hSoAKntQsnCzrvGohDs0ACajdqwFRU8IeId9wtKGhB759iliqxOAgVlfWYQObhAU0@GN25AxGl9XBXIFSuegDW64NliwH4b3uRvNtJHanL3ZhgCHlQ7FVWG8WPgf2dAHlg7kZ0r6BjjmAMMlmGzE5DiAjcuKzEEH4a8H59wukSwpsZuQEgwhCFIDFFIV/NM4WWhXcgkc7pke37pSbOt1cXGh0f5yk5GtWR7u1O3hEaPJYdcGndhNjq3BUJyJZONZeALu3KTyDfrx4NmdKR35Wrwz429J6ngVMachFu14Uawcz3Ej6u6A9qXBDWE8YqgHNm1i34qJaRic/4x64tLnvxLyn1qIXiEQxhDMNDFLtBIALNFsnSU6F@2ycDinAgnAIRct3xL3dBz5HwPPN9nDTuDDHdNqA/@72T@jAU2AJPOu03nUPIW@z5n/Kb6H9hQCOdYF2x2NzFmM3BX0jQwcm5Haw2ZQ7ZMLGKGaYZd8g0F7WpvVF4JPg@BQqflNHjbCTWeky/VA@W6T6D7l7lNwn3L36TxSP9ratM5VMrS6wuQg1@NeZb5PBDPz/VzxnRnnLgQZFGumcxDoc7ZgdwV3q0KhfXrzL8jHis8YwBNDILgVS9ZenNZO645nXWzV48kuMLtMhIAcB9C1OtH0oh2Ykfr98/7Q9RasHNyiDmolgTdatXqCGzivYBqDDCLG4PSycVex7kAMrnOFQCQYIKAeBo6oGuyOY7ZSDrY3JUdgnJo8pzFHrCaQqZP2JZyEHahLnPScsGFA9RAgtA@SBGiCC/NLDj@XwZcOz0d4/LTvV6Wt5Ae4u020HgVKXisqXNaUKZNCWKmqjyaQHdXVyvWk@O6QFbVrTqFkXon8D6O/8dHod6BcLMeeGJZXGGUpXFRwkheoEKK4EFVZtRLKV8AguWX2rRHUXPtcPxW1NUSzlfSbGTweTIJ3gYdNxkKZ31J4/tD6L9mRSwErzCoVSOKswoslLxc@STnBg2CeCDbzGUGE5wIEYKSWBrNEsGk42LRS4YKDTVcEuwghOSUkpzwI9z1dgWRdBIPWU3BKMWZPHbRTnFImAzydV6OgBg1lhidO4nD1K9x5C0cpRZxzmUNcIHgIVWzks1Z9aey1ENIhoXUNADLiDQBtfsRTSbou8HQ1@ApkFCelL6P4l2ADLiuAwUgEl/nulLGAyagNDAq/HKd6AMquHK9Jsk79uvhL8VtO@Jb@rd@0TC361BctwxOI6PePYllHyoYKaEj70FMZFMjYknkmzuZe0DkieBpizwWtrnnhstgSZRvsk/6x3slm320mByZOEcGDX4LDvhW//YBjIuzu0B2bYzeTKfFGk01styx@3mawu44LTZPwrrSg67Vdy3OiY8jUltt1bM9K4PHiXGW3aMIC3@JbCuvJwuh6kiT6IHkzFkFzvkJVt9HAo@gajRhOHVNKwWxUmkmG7BmNStj@BVMoPIgnAfRwGHObr6zWWLkdJm6gLIKd2K2z2OFQOEYhkl0GMqwF@j@49kCDYZ47bznSVq6oSjfHMdpIvucO3C5ofRNPkzD0NfAHc9iIkDkcEi4JZmKTthTaRptKSayVMBUR9LOPDso@M2KmEoQ3FgEsECPBRtdpjJQdLYmusTI6HsyP7/jj8T0O43u8Hl9qhV/HmTfNK9zx46JOx@YQwOMcjfTtaGDSQW61b6CzgEpgjXoVD/DBKLZpClYbMd0Fr7vCu9YB/kgEXx58BYh/vor@6zPQD77/odln4vmcxzOQNwOcGRijLf49f3AzBt4PFEWKLIkuYO37HxgX@MXTVR6gCgFqLAkuB3ehhII5hGa3F@yN7gO@hedxJtUNvqfpVRXuuASn0XmCnRmrs@h@o231zZnVjgmfiRBcP8VH0GAjefVhCUdBR0LP5W29GNRdSuAK1TgSnXsqrWAZM3GuKKvZinuxA@6hnnLC8GA1/dD9hmjGLr4K762GdkA0ijuiOec2dn8OZ8MZ3@i4z09mEHKU1z88J3GV@@0EATqIfV4S82iVdeLzKBYk6QNqhMCvtphk3IfUh4hbfN7Mw48j0e0phcwNBar4uSwtbtq/PMftdTke4gqfJ/m40Yex5G1M98E8F2I1DmwuwvY@rgq5ARnnY7RasTBEbrM2x1znhkxAO@qnc1bUKo0lAjUISZJubFNzm/QLRcKW8QG8scPpc3gjwK41bnCG8tOGfVriyBRGLgNzGNJahA0o6QAlREVOcoFGyJfkm8H75VUQZ2tlnK0bcbYW4gxKwGKUIU9SayFKkQuYPeuyoG91xiukMzph2xle68Q2XI5rjrC34jJqR0t2gkXPoyUQyFErWtqPgVCOtqOl@2TwoqVjMpxFS5@BYV62om@jJb9YoIcRfJLhLtoLEY7frWhpL6ZcSWPzzPL8eLVoKchT8LPDP4kiQApMN2iNOMTmuCKZ45EFFRsplQmGHOMlsPlE/TAJulPw58dw0Hb@6Ih9nFvkmcWZvlBphGoMHg9UG/520UtKcknU5vuHD2g@U@AFo4lDGy8chsCDGh6JLgojjhi60ogGvAFBlJul5RixUE32geiI2IFDKZMX4yfqaaQPtGPkXgPP9XkkdPaKCO/n1yIInoEfhicGXoXnDXT86AgjHJNVlqCFRH0ZXZMozOtFXETuh3OI@roXPeEBt74XnksENiTTQYejwTmMbOgOF5mEXHFyvB0OQ51yvFAi914LRlJBlMwVzmQtUoaCIVz4lXXJCYVD1BZEEDrWUnVeyoJ6gWQxOs1lXUhT5YUPUAjJHCjhVuuMzrW5L4zkj4ubBNUVq6ohPyyPkiTXopiEwBpu1zMxxzz2oPG6j5v4fFzz1Q85xb6WGAIIhQxi4fLV/Qj93eX6u69Q@0S4FsEyxXp5VXpTvV5by17DvD@P9mYGomOC3VeWKkdBDHOSQ@sgpJmv47UbKj5O@eBKPo80gH5N2/fJFrQJbqHb9bYFh4Vawuh80fLMAMszYzWhbmok/XPNV1o0jEnA4QkPMJ0nbT2uPOHLshhdqH/b7H90Bo8WMziceQiPEjC6RnJeykcTh2a5zMs2iG1ugyJVLzEuyGm4NMjmuSWIexq6DYZtweKwcXT/8Mmjr0Olm8/nFVFHz@b4YanFvtagHueQaXJ0UB8sabYYCTyqAge7sTueDpPeOHXkG7KEC2tQBkyIxWc/UcYVIctC8vxa2YVw3G@IogLW2bwYmAtSCVUdE6tsW9B1DASxxrEtUwDx1Vugd4JaawodytBo4AHCjQZVX40GTl5qNEQthlnjj4grP4tsJCfeiA4w5CeKXEgSrbNn9w/Z84e7J@zk4T578GzvM/b1w2fs@e6TE1wv/fTZvUcHewzu/SfH@0xamB6Jpy9hgxLoet9qWXhKHu51lmEEec8dzrjcie0p3P7YHLCHbsvCYaptzxzc7fEPzbHGVR5qH5qjM@zDtOmErYE9xvkWdDwUNGNRuWnT4jucy8/AbxPatANs8w7ctt2xwa@Ebd@hbXn@GjDWtyEHQd76y1oTXEnCk6Bo6hCd2YYzsC4guAn@cewGwJh8/hWd0Wx7PIDV1pggXHB9NAVP9o8eHzNckb93@OT@wcnB4ZNj9uDwCD6ffv3gyadAz4Pjk6ODe8/QiTw@Prx/8OBgb5csOAIpjeGa@FcTb7wWBQ29E1VaZzjyTUdxB1@Lvd6owbMLk5Yheiw6cVD62GbffmO1o2Vp4qH6gksfaaiAxTZ3jz79HOp8Zr3GEU5/KJjmH8jPPDqRbDPFtik2KCxVKG9lUVyh2lN1hcYjBjOGBxRYZVr@HiNzgvnAaRJP27aYvIdzVLDvm6@Sp7Lsg4aINgA2gvInrFQYHSwSjSa2CWQVYmv1XdznkMfGJxGKDwx6159qUpaIYmKuDALF9QoHDvYH6eXAAvgeLAwR7XjEPbB0YME9sAy3QFX0AOeOsKzwMRkfTlA8sxy3eDUYPqBhYZYPLO6Z1IotCJx4vlGWmiw4mAn3DOjT8TG8l4eOtTO9lm1TEI/849Eq/T4vGBY/1AtkIh9KpLlt4FMGYdPBoQYx7Y0ff4muwA04T8jsjD0WqygaO8HJQZZj84N7un3T4VOg5lN3iPdYAXeFqYhptnZw4A2tABm6xIB42NYiHkG4@0IrtD40HIS8dyNGU8yRpEPn/ClotyFw7wYCPw8YAKQutHRaVFPRalME43YEK8c8FzgS@23fhf0DO7cnLWshgJi1FXtlv3mjCCInFtpJ/jxFwg6y6I01ArWShjI77gjKOIlVOiIEpWCr5w7HNs/D2GIKaMSJqjnwjRUbxPayUl2IDelwPUbHdUKRNoGLV8TaBKb8kFiJ4/nYeSC@5udFAudDJczn3SE6ZhOPop6PnSVwEOnCwu4XUIRprBw7P2djwoTrn9JcdrxjeORcoVK9f@9UffcygefOcbHAj3r0Jx3iDYyJcUHxoHE@mrA4Qr1LlDT/vCBv0sTQYg6ekJZYyn1g0A7s2dCuu9soB258uvFNe1wjc92eLN@@rfBQKkomcfqn14vNpVuC1fwoExSmzsQUkJDsBGRB1sd8mwTBDOT1XVwXg7lQBoo4KEew3X7tNB4hQvzUNScdkCziUESR3QF8hVVpRsX8jFhc2RLOj@SL2L1KvKok5xNKWIicMV9EJ3zIuqKEpqVQfXUD3P314EB@fzi4wlrsePXwUdDur4X2Ubip8dWweLUUgvXhYN@tAcsrt58LLKQ9sRowryRvQgs4PWDOxGYkmE27PsaXN/KOyh6AwboXe1ACoKHYJg4NUfu7Csd4ACUMZq4QHZ/c3z86YjJvn0BYkHvYZGgLMYiwN9jT@Wxb2yFhpwVKU9BYDpQn32ZhRpt/rSvMS4m3QlQIHSQh6BEIi/lpyB17yqWeqFlIhaDZ9yQQfcotYnfpyyCvJgBfQRsQkJ1nWiiB0tJkRnjlY3vhSeCCbgmuG4fn8NMMa15341GDo1kYUHhOkNnFlSXL8@85149LfjxcwcIdbjDBbdCkob6BdsIxRDwEj5q2mINrssXPUpxkzxXsiE87nPiVWtSw//4MRYzElXCuC4fEulCOBWpcP9701RyakIjVgIkzPYUjn9EMDr6IJ5vtcIYq80ovtlgFgZKJh8/dDXMFBK9flYPj0GPzerISKOThsrZJ2NR8LOvYOytgl1d7@gTnQueui4frUYG0XRuV@g8TFa8lFmLyab40Mb4jQM5ls@n/p7hn22ob2fIZfUUhk2CBLNskEIIxiQGTuA@XHAxJswxxC1s2Pm1st2XA7sCsM/MwPzDzPp8wv3L@4TzNV5zZl6pSSTaQXnnorBUsqap27dq167Zv9RzsZCtU8cyPwuY1JDl/jq4HcL6PQIaTkMT7wLmVQ1elRwzwBOnYtF4NmERB2OrMWFNibafFyMQPcGG5ECCD0bzxPr9krY4YJ3CbDZ1XJBM6ZZlqgzGEdUN51ExR/@Hp6nBCfra@@T9eHw82zISmgw9olX/QH4ZB5JVnRFExPqH/avxbMBz2KBv7M10jlDS5MT3pbEfedmzwyq3CRNK3mS1pSe8kNrt1layBKiHxoodXeKJ0r5AU72XyBbOpe5X9sliiKHutmCzSHtqOMffMd3pPIUBzMMklcPkgH74X4Qb8BxxcBRLIRN58aaKN8yxuRBHYNdfohhVpFirn1nyy91thw@9hSA/XfhEK230JBUkKWz7ac2ZJ1nOFWHlALhz00lDKtTOeTUXhGwp0EVIcBPcmfjcWLPTUUJaST1y87mfz67m1txa1rueO3Ova2wt3qVG0BSy@fu86vBneNX9t969uW6IrBn@7HDcmv/8mxOpr8QrqWnnJEVbza8Ushad8A3/Xxdscca5E8B1Fiz23hfD4sjchFkV0Di/MC77ojA7NG@ghkeBSsXStuBBd7EbF69raRbFXzBWua72LAjr5jZaLo@X8cho/vIRVFOYY1szXRhe4pppS16B3K/AOULqrTbqGCHINgS8H/rDT3y8dfohJ43ADgCIwaetNAnW@vnMOrdnQ98TrBXdpKSZzBXKshRska468gvLo007yZBTHNDuAGfSKC7vZcEx/J441l/NuBqM@pahIfMha4r5zb80pN6YcSRQgS62j4vXRreXhOMqTRsUQf52wFXUmz9u1PPpOOgaIGpak6dA@t230KUREpS9X7cIKvcBvXCESeF/tPRUTm5t0ey2wWuiRFA9NOfwhOUzkLvARFSDwMyBtA1ZBO/eQ3D4saD6@5/GBv5CMakR@MmQgb9FOEVPQ/Ft8I/8mKr8JBGDCz/Gey5MiTrnzgo0k@w6ScAFDksUP/qhmQLdK7pQ5bCzC5vqKEXCyFCcaYbWSTPB97g7JybSCf7IFmTy9TTVD53c4O5GE9NTyLURaUpdS0hb@dKNiaaNYRhVTmQ1SzD1LDZR0wfHoIIBhNRE7QbcLSDMt5iJy4CP598r6l3X9YQ3rvNDIc3pmKj0TS/c4nZGKcnmwwEeZNsxMdupblO9B2FE2d6quoqDNiwc93fBgSxLlLTyVN/RG/Xonyrylu5K5UidsxhIyRsrXGb3PKfOxMprBdXqN0yV/r8ie11jG8r6P14@/luyggIxnpa1Jgku9Xqf7jhctnYJsZgM1heDi2N/EdjwopQ@mnE5gB4dyfhq2W8UIynJezTg0Zuytzfe2JzcZ79JJNNiLcWpgzRgjBpWozmUi3JgcFqEeSp43QBBMZDShRu6WKjyRhScGWMw1r6plL8ipAQ5NSw7xIvpF3uMfNdjjyKl8qdmJc4z5mBvP3s1xAtGkO2/PJlN8NkF3Ef4oG/XEKhLVPUlCnD1JHBpSYF1nwD7YLRSDz@t5wpwo1EwxRXedIikdZcgr9n2sCzHxwfpXdsn64MMee9ANxqKExwyfvLCsmIP7KAhHIcZ2olg04c1g0EWtI2347siFWgYKWVlFdUsE0VjZPauClj2c38Un6ZAOhTxxhJDv0EAkSghv2m10JkMP2P4dTq0ocemMPKvUm7BAA8bMqxV2Mw/ETchaUzjtt00kuOd49CClw4HfCDwL9mgh7H4sbmqLx7eUp6PfCEYPgyVtw7L@etNp/LrzAfW5b/K5V3mDZLdSHZzzXr2OHKyASCphJQfb2NX8a8sydMMN1g1nEKAr9nGh/wy8GdwGvV5glWDFoIwhbFrDYHgbND3LOg60EhjhIiujZhL9sPs3wwYLd2DT5QMzopdw6LI6DDgMf3F9ZnVxg3RlroVKq0jbDF1922kiAZXHSauP2mFSWGCYAKYHFroORkCUJUfEUSLds8SF9i7XKIgCamCcE0M3ocnQ6486DegZkmRZXQDFapCosl4zgQnU1@j66BzszUIA3WMiCigElCrpKRwsqTT/QzgI2TClY/dVz2Rh9uvTWIHhHgw7MPtGBKZeoWIG7tDBJx8rVVE92jv5UjouC3j@dHz0ubJb3hXbZ6TjRkU5xbYVH4/2YXbR2nTWmh/BB7tUhZI2JVilwzNR/vnTcblaFUfHonLwab8C0AD8cenwpFKuuqJyuLN/ukvad4AgDo9OxH7loHIC2U6OXKpVFbOicuJoTxyUj3c@wmtpu7JfOTmjGvcqJ4dYGWr1S@JT6fiksnO6XzoWn06PPx1VywIbZu1Wqjv7pcpBedeD@qFOUf5cPjwR1Y@l/f1EQ4@@HJaPBRkJGK3cLgOWpW04wmJN1M7dynF55wQbFD3tAPEAwX1XVD@Vdyr4UP65DM0pHZ@5Emi1/NdTyASJYrd0UPoAjbPSz1AF@mXn9LiM8Y@QEtXT7epJ5eT0pCw@HB3tEq2r5ePPlZ1ytSCs/aMqEey0WnYF3gJHVQMMoBakw/P2abVCdKscnsCacfoJ7R0c6OQvQBjAsgRFd4nAaAaBrQUiHR2fIVSkA3WAK758LMP3Y6QpUauEVECLip0TMxtUCEQ8MZspDssf9isfyoc7ZUw@QjBfKtWyAx1WqWKGChpknAHrQKWn1GrsJ8CLH4FZLcW5LnWnqOyJ0u7nCmIucwMHVCuSW4hsOx8lzT2MhmsIUTp9lBn416ZgpTX96TbA4JLTEpnZMhodMWnnaLcMK7IMVmVHCaew6qwnQimZabDS6ER4jYWsaQaXN@16p9fqo4@pLsaCj@uw7eJ1Kg7eKnFuPXFrhZSvUIFUql7/XKrDQbdarzvu95SMofFcCSkGfyqXI9uI4fLx5I2Cn40NpvtmjFBbL6Wikwz1UAGBOZn6L9n0zb8OHJHNNgNZDJ33EbASHYWsNrlCVQpMjeTsiFdfRFWSZILeO5IdqGBagfcadZSTomUkZeqH8Kd3H73w4mB8gNmZxV3ZLB5iCY3O74GqhiuhkAj0R0Yk6LSoSi8Mgl/b6ZxZHZ75vXa/30w7jipDeUdwDmynnWeKXwbtRPFMsjwhS2pnGUs/VOdu2sJo/bMkmZD94g2pZWn8Ux/Rj6Ow4ZgPKDWlqkhYLYWW6ZdcHC2SXCFDW6B7BXUy7vkOSj9XvuBpLrfyupD4/lF/57GF9oIYhBYWvBqVu6CfjxecAQYYxeIAknRkhIxs1iij7E105jvIeIWZ7jpNtPyBtfoqoHUdSAIb2Ru/a9aJq/GwMzaxh3n4w3HpYPt0bw@mTsT29frqm7WCpcNu/ezy7xnWQ5FiKerYANZx2KdRkjFKdmDjQyPFiKUdsT8xcDaLGTHOuuo0@ohxHrTdRtySCScybG6I98D00ETPDpAOtqAAHPOW4teZI1MyQDrWVAdbc@2PaYvvw16JeEAas3Qn1Gtj/IOw9fBXQ1w3SDKQZDGKnQucC6cLmvfsPWUqSocbCtyDWTxb8TGHcdM0IFEX2c@idy29Sd42ejFkU0Ycr9TtVBKQmE9iIZRdRY9H9ieKMyIFwBQ9DL78LPkNHs9kgDsKd@eHo9KoCmTc0yVRTh0Jo2WjaxLyxVYRuujlS13TpkApvyORorEnxck6MIgxGggVvBgEbXzjgAs6jkiySrKAfb/oiG/MqRi8A@EUJMfKd@DcWc2RUAoqfoh8V1EpBMPSQU6Yane6DktlOdNxLBQ5Y2T6IXoQ/D@RJjPgb8KJE6BH1DKCAH4XJQkq0wqOr0SUzp1SNBjajYia5qezCMyD2TFXumFSezNm/xoggeydifpwRmEPW@kZBEAmR8GGOX61SdqVD0en97Yji6OepNe4HqSFXCvUUjEFN7N24dK2y1W6FXxxhMOyJqPCfSgq3vPB7ZJGPRyZEkd58SK0GZyj4n9kl0gAogc8cekVW60mOSsnR5maB2SoJWPBaeqISbAtfXhUa7ckjBCZsblfar4UoQD0FuIz3U66AKQv2Dw3HnGRVmJxQlHwMB44HpNx8ZEh6y7JELMbIJwXTRKG4B0hoztcILoMnUL1RdBE@gUZimAlkdVhFGcQp1vHA9LSsnqnsSfJJHKoxv60x4HoA5ZqqRweB/iQGJru8p448CeAcvf7ms0sll2q9l20XcTKWCwhy@N9KI1@fwhbRx/bDTi6nYnjiS9S6BD0wpuhjF8I61lnKCUSatMP1eC2iU/vtMxwDHhCLeyM0Fuh6RF/UJOuA7QQ5fAk48yaSAPzKh7dUkLHzng5L9KbUcom0ITCkhIRN8WauL/nXExQGTI0IAp2Qn24IJtNqgf1Dnr43fWHv@Laj1ugXjNo6sikBkiSBXInVXoU47Ex4qari6CgK1ACoimRZ0GaNlSFNfqNZCdp12RH0TExdim15I/Xo5lUWUtBRRHjytqB@dYy0JlIpRUZGlQHC82vrBIqsw5cD48exihaaFxtLezznp5SNngTUXyhto74xPOmfjrDJynkL74IcfTAF9Rxyy0oIox7VtSrTs9zhB/aFHzpBMOmKROFnUzTH6D4jY4@/R7xohIdyrB/DX8UBhM4ATSynXGWYNTTP/WvevWdftdvd/odH85pGMZ9zDMePk7oETusPezfhXTVDyU0jUzNSfTM8WU4DBu@a71kwQjNFY6CQdo0UxgNJ6UrDhNBknM0AozucyT@HiRjpOkyr1ejQlbc/5Ts8fJO4dGyr/KzCrNGHwHICW4rYUHBPqQjckwynE8LUxkun8pg4HgpMsJ3HrHYi2H8FkhEapgYxgqZKbMEsxF4MnsU41pz7DYpBuEQAy0FuwFeOROm6bPr4825MIu8Q0uBDZFfzxlFWYsyxjiE@DB5nNwrb/5k7AGBH0A//2oWt8xiBJriWiraUsjnFRllFHAh88AOzdE0E8Ms1mnDKtSNAa2Pk1DjyZPHqEGWP7ApkmH2prgSR2QaDj54e1y6DlNOfeLgorIoFh2K24FbkNIonXucYYPn7Gdp8KMSlyVnODHtSMhpA@nHSNUAKuEloQnzWhNljqn8/IhZWfneXksQsDjL5My4DDdtq50LeaB0eH1FtVZ/CJOxnaCeNPVYDEf9weJ3Uu/RuWNmZLZZtG44zrOGwMxsRVgsl5pE2uIEHycFK4lPgmniFCNLM@AhPL7Ss2bzJBHHxTqOt2J98gwdHqNZZDelFxXd300e@7go3qJFr1po9JAi3DFIaUF/r9Wh4fXHZxAJk49XdZox6jhl1Cf8aIBKkElT6fspRNwncU/QowmUw3qbQDuzfx4latJIToU8VUmxIJdITwzcjk6bMC8NWmh8gWHieIerJym94Ry7E1Ll5TOXGGQYExgg7oqDTCSHYglu1FkJPqLbAVrpOloL5XEmgqct08JBB/3XBKOo/FK4Iy0e6pNM/qLAkMYaEpwqKNdTkJS/ObzW6mOCMkUKGOIzSKFbNDU3XX1/q360LZAPIHBpSpaWvjkXG@OIZcAG/phJ9THugaOqZMnYiIoPhDpNDTAW4JTS7gZ8XMXdX2fIHI/WDXIYwQGCP6fxZ1mWwHDeazlNbSwybk4wiyPJzaPNEZktLhIxFL8j@eVQ5K0uHVwBQMAYQ/liHiBgWFPCHpUCFHrH5LwYorKPoGAxj8MSPlJU1MjOc0Y6ElVmeL1q5MjNyvHWhJGZCQQ2FrPzRIjAnmV2lggKLHQzcTFyvJndnigHbIgV7zPFoStkr8RpqHuOCQiPhK2eUWp54eYkB1Pi61Unlqj5m1Lf5ozUXDIV6KMxrGXyydT1XCw1Vu3KSrxorCTQwzFrjSUCKRwTYT0r/Ng/ck0xQ55rm1DjkBHbZUj77B4epe7w3Ob9LRSb5JSt9hgKnukZro5fdb5iJRaU/ekA7GKRVAYYu/2HW6ssUxUm8q4AikunnF3SfCCkHauNSz02C0@6KtKeDlCgzrT9lvh8srcXC/t6OVGGRtfBcDWXyyETX5rB75VtNYqSOv1sPHe2ddPtZgd3Pw0/X2Zp7g8CuhJgQ52gA@gSGBSh1x@2@WYIxAGyYu6MdGTFs/5Nq2VewYAaSuw86DbOKaMhCFqAOtro5fMJCYAIpFxgf8EGYvt@EXr03fm80ZRQlBoKSqNJ8K2ttGdAHvzQQvtsrakiYDgxK2smWLec4tY3XEHwZhPqLApf7HyLzJPtj0G323fFF7wsGCMFzD0kC@ztmQVynAU1jOTdexNSPFpXBLedruFXjFlMXkdwamFS90youPAYG/84aJfHg7Rd@2rDsgJNXsZmLmN8alfYbduRweK/AyzzIaD9Xbmv/UG6QXRKZoalXo7g6AkwepV3Z559YlkckolJmj2fG4k6G12PgjVA0x3aC6hY9tS91JJHsmvi2ufjfAtpmGMYEieMufJ9JdDV7M@bFm9Hrdb3zYp0DQB37B@aEfkmlB@bEEkHQCNQDj@gJ0bR/ksGhvVeIqAIb3Dwso7peQcL1LGAZb1oFH@7S5dKJbEwWF4WpdI2PGQyorRdErv4YXtb7ML7Nr6/LK6srhZ4zt11vsHHbfXxQWwDDJJwLjeuhrvwCmlF9BtDa23s4oVsccEtLNSLm1uFMFsrbaNbPzz989//85//8V/Zknz5H3zZppfaV53J87zsQuPbwsuHAr7Xdi8WFy5rC4OLxXYBuexfFDW8Xxll/Mh81BteWileBYyvZEeqztkUfUYWFepWv2t/@CvMLhsi1QizKfk15JujaI5NNQLje4B@lJdwhFeXDiSP8oBECoBOUBwPvdMI0AAP1hugJOCCdqBcnnUrSnCP4WB0Bq1VSclIPLRnvQ3QpyWKpIC@uLBiZTq9MOihBPyW9rzcPMvy4bczqkv@zX49CNvb/bFYOk@LpZxYcsWSbdNPfu0tfHUWsh30zuVscBywbRdSItUCmhmKsEMbPTo/0F07CXJb1gJd2YOQVJgKysxecK4@/ZGzDF@4FratObw0U7CIhJRMWCT1baH3AN3yDXI82DFXG9oo1OUphiozNCq6f3EL5IdsCBDVfM0E2ehDlajpI49kfMqqL7KvLbpNiAAjWY8/7NG4xw@wFi30pM1z7CyF1xyR@Tx/xbWxwM7QhDamcP0RAqRQ4eNkjjwJF1OLFlt5G62kZrIXttk@yXxs6zAJRso2nQv9mzCYgK25TcIt9KRfizTkZvWKsDtavWJUZSdtv4VlFLm@6Y46A@muQLXjgPqma3vgkYQ9SoAYDsfs35geYSQoUJGiEt3Cl2VNRLOPTeeR0JOu6dDBjseaI4MI2a9pGNv3ibHtZMlLRLED8wAhpU35Wn6nG8qoK0MidtsfXuLtgH6LLlQbsd6M5Hl4TWoC435LI@0RZDI5j8YzNCU1GPrta98VqcP@ydCfVGDZgp3PqOE50EIMwYRI4OCTVc9qnkKYWyS7hCiim0KWQ3h5QXcir0fjvrW1zwl2qRoKMuwKDoIYOxElg/tYXyXoGHH1H@gEE@WpyVtrI@UUSzMvWhpJSLbpNkPDbGroWKoGc@zogWNbjKoemYoXZKEbXGivSfELM3kXYwTIum3pBShdEdbeYv24OrWDnh9bnAZdSzn6ZwuC10Ucz3QVJVsjWerm03x04x1iBfvIr/EoELw2qXBG1lw6PXceyuvcUuY6QkG@tS1@1hcdfQEdXWBGniHitNfhyTKxQkV3YHiiQpb/AKHV9duA3@TOnyArnqfS7@azTu3ree9iKX3euz//3SFM5JSsVtmMSElltpqx5FiBlTHrxl6VVVqoQg2e9@IZznuCfVgMEgAi2XTta/biPgsInafwTvnzFBMk1mWISfbp@rIIPjuFZiqORTZlzTlLjur89Lu8I2BtpV/sQ/7g8C9goQ6VJKaHc86wBaDIT/e3G3Y5CbPrK7nXK/nXcBJqB@PMMLjB9TYT3lwGY9hKhHichaXn/PcYN8QI8TAO/QJ8HEM7@VoT9j0JpZOSnELlMKd6LM1WUMZjnoD8QGUKl4ouLo7O46PyEQ/8rgCWU3kpFhSbDhrcl8b1M@xfYz1@iPNa0juEORKtDNhGhESoGYSsLl95jEMdNVwWyc/JEzsYu5WAQPdmU8Zq0ev3MnKz5niLBdxEo9dMdz23nkuO0akhGhuhC3IztTgv8lvv3vzjv49@S41SWyvZL0P4HaV@S62tp/gRHuDtlXq7TW2lNjHb2kNqkoUzMDy@@cf/QvmtnwAOpkw24c/WqoK1NkltZYpU5D61tQYP@ZUVqPf//v53aMMCn9jwLtaFuisIsYKiyI7fI96FdFHBVvKxdDGaVsgxC2GwhSGczeEFDaPGK@s5EtOlpFXFbSAjXyl7FLnEk2HWiEyFWJKh7ClgZ8QFilhBhkEqE4qWMGw3lNkGMm@EpvjlhbcWwgngF2nOoavUphsvQjQZWuBjEXRgmmuE8zw/bOXe2dq8Y8NWNiUFtYXEo52ca9dfFf4f)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/hvjw9)

IE8 is separated from IE6/IE7 with `document.compatible`. Space on line 492 is for Retina.

`d.body.style.display='block'` is not needed because of `* + body`, removed. One would think that now IE6/7 require
`d.body.style.color='000'` because of `*{+color:fff}`, but they work without it.
I think `d.body.style.display='block'` was needed due to a bug in IE6/7. How to
reproduce: take polyglot #265 and comment out `d.body.style.display='block'`, run IE6 or IE7 with the name of the file on the
command line. You will see empty window. Now press F5, after that text appears. IE8 doesn't have this bug (the text is visible
right away). `*{+color:fff}` is not affected by the bug either (the style is removed as it should, text is visible).
I tested it with IE6 installed by default in Windows XP SP3 and with IE7/8 from Utilu IE Collection 1.7.2.1 installed on Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

## 316. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE9), 14555 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=x-UA-Compatible content=IE=99>ss<!--
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
# 
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa






















































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,+i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:>Ex Cr Uitharbody$/ $5"3c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]p 8ogr34*61  prstd6,1 ,8R ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on;z op>s'0}e}equ7+?4[0]tfc;[ ].c5:2>"r"
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@PadSD4s5H5I65AvSYhEiABfpMi1Wq1@j35dbfakvr1syk@NkiCJFogwAZIiWy1umzPrjeeZGczHiflODN5jmcy62ymarJTOxtnJ5mpSn6dSs1P@QM6H1tbqa34P/Cecy4AghJJqZ1J1dbWQiJwP88999xzzz33u617g5//PIYPe@ZYs77ljNnY8Mas65rnhquwBzN2Xze9vJYVBAy16/YnQ8MeexUhxlTGvLHujpml2/2J3jdYDFw1Nrf3TGtsuCnmGQZrG5ZzAf5Zxmzjgh3YHbMLkNjYOTNs843hgl@OsYeG9Xb4dsw6znCo212PjVzTHpNvnrFnOlh6k84Z09ve2NU7Y9OxwavA2HPb0oftrs4o@Mg1eKQiA1CdM4qz6FNi7Injegak4HQMz3PQsQyOums6j3effnwtvJphH@uA1MgypteSV1X2wjTc7vUYGvvs5NGj665Z9qns2OzRTZTUHNudjJ2D8XX4ebbbN2ydaUpZ0a57FoCYY8MqZUqZBS/we2S6UJq6X2qVecnYk2HbcIH4fhFemOOBAhFOHE5w5tjWjBlTAAY49iCYMWYmlhbLZzIYEv6PjY5jd@fgwckAOADXGI7GMyYz2/F5ALwcl3kjvWPIXcMyh@bY6DLLBOycno@Nx6DA2Zkxu3BcKHiZsyIh4o2MjtkzMYqfA09AZntotCd95kzGowmg57Gu6eltC4K1Z6xr9PSJNU6xNvgB8cj9YmDYPkqm3cd8vJi7IAQbqgDHflMF2piWxQCdM0QHk/bYNnpcoDsGbRuEpdFFUPtzcgEk3fKC3C8mvJAMxnvmOn1XHwKjdg2iwWcHz5jXcVywwQ/D8lqwDkxHH7PtbRbff/owzuohGRW3LYQkrbFLxlgs8GTnujUxPDbUZ5C2PYbKxRwqvyCGAMFZfCNeYfFslmkZlsuxHFS2EtPyGQZVogwGqLVaVoVfgWklllOB7/PxFKbTc/W@aRkcSt@xegioiByr5ZkG70wunuK@HUqjyLIlViiyYp4V4V1mZQ0SQYg5ppbz8CvADyCUAQMVftkcTylkC2QnyALbYz19aFozDn00QvAdlldZESACmipA1koAoawhhMUnCm88AMIO9HMAKVvmGYoLI5QYWFpp@KS3ttIkslA28iS9gWFZmCoQCkiUL7EipFqATOcgZaCjVtKCzPcHlH3Cq5iBH@BYhByXgLwZoFQGSVWEH9hBDGkgbzQQLhrIC00Fdw3MWYQK4QrgV4CyKoSk1bpEW5CuEFdFYqJAUZEGEI1B0WVzDAovB8WbxeLNZxngCQgUCwxkSkllpRwrFRmQq5xhQHoVkMGyV0GWqYCEisCgSFUoUxUQUYFZVACqZvNMiNBVzaI/xM1CXCCBmoM4OTBDuagF/EE8KHgVklQhTU0rz1kLcNPykMl8lnhOK0DhFcEPiKUBrhpwiwbYaiXwx7glIFwJWbIYEEK3RgMdaQElgIwMrAYEyQNOBBvCg1krZjlLUei2MTY7wpUAtYq3gFGJE0gPlAAgTZjOsAEFBpxzTyKUgBIIpEVhNfEMC7gIZEhHBzOyLdR2lBwBHHOsoJyFZspwzrEhpeq/kIxHIqLtYisK8qpruC7DsNDYeikSJt6k7RmvJ9jWzvHqgXQyQLD2dNMKEaCqo4@pHYBv3IP0Zoto91xnSPVriMLCcpzRCrELoukCAX3iXBhz1OeSSx@NLJDn4G4AISa6Bchc6KQPkLoQTZUjBJEwXmdgAkBKCuSq6Rodor2fdYidBQm8iGKFafV7WYTyINIsZNnIAaHqYRx7YlkVaO6MDsvW013jPI0uvOlYbDIQh6AxgfbQB9HWoS2nxhSxCCHd0xRqpk6CkvWc4WLWuHg5CLM@MLEJsC70GZReDySLMdWHoHEwbNZtaLiHwDG8BLEkPN7wHLCuY8fHIZQLF5pXyHSYEwBpEU3G5tAAfcyBKFjiOUIahRth1p4BKxO1cgqpYxyTa4RShOuE4g65iAOvLNCwdScdpBqmbdrEQdAgeNRa1QEuVzoVNECVcw29y4OhdoEYRfQjaO0MILqvCnQIEGoohu2BtuMpzES1EBi@7/SAx6iJBlUDos7T6VDeMeeh01TpKAJRGvlmeGYxk3VGIwbuoJ8AWo8yJWhjnVcmewOe1sBjVmfiujM2HUEBmEMINe44vR4w7RtjNAAQbNhlnVkHaiXkEplG6DokgTqja1kObZsGhLENyPbes6@zvgHUhha5B5gSp88zMBpRFogUus1ba1sHSmEWOqMZkQXAhDF6jqOge9cxPOIR0GbCGo@JeUafagRUr95cBg1R@wDmBI3ABpYFgePXKoSPCQpLM4NJ@YX/sWFDjekAM0Jdh@JDfXSX9UD3jzTWqNzpnY4xGvvs4ZAUM@2IQnP4CBUacpV9YIo3EDbvgy62gIEAQYWAcyItuH5GwhUVfdKzdBSxfgcD2nTbCFVYxgWKNbuRPIQ4v5a6@BLDLGDwUlyBw4hqAmp3JBsmY5QgKBTNzgBF4BiFDGkZUMncyc3sg1s0eXfI5F6YNmKjgrQRlHTohHishiHDz7oJSBlZCKu@4IBBFxxuAa17wyWQnRBJqxt1VdK6ArLwNqBDx3aWQAVihnAxyKIPlQUx4zFKDd0KmZGqi7dQRiin531fbL@g6RyNHBdqBhc6M5RkvMgi3OXwfkoibCIk6DcvtqjQUsSxnR@PeZ9rZEE/iKoY1lTQJ3WQFCDEeA8AZJ7DU4wgTLWeYPn4XZDE58wETahtG6iS6u6MA4HsQasMCc2Y6bogBs@xbeBNT9CGKMSn0BTo3S5KViQH1fvriSvI0XuTtjm93s3ooKPyyhPOdZf1sIfhgq4BlSgR73lxqUruFDPiJaad0ThNUflbhIAUSIEiT/Sg0wINwSMQNMczu5MQF6qYmGLiZNwriRIYMCJXzdhX9dH4OnavwA2ZZngG9ZpsVdaHVluW4S2jG2GCHmkFPXQX1AuohKBll8vdts7egvRwmTzdo9ioFtJXVXJhWobdDdPyCYG4RPOr8CQ8t0MGOdKqYQ4wOOWcGokFAt6REhRRBId02m8/0YGUPO5H6gx3nNg0PMASXAOR2GWookMDkCBkTNA5zI45bvlayr17gb6yUasBs4ESBWKzK0WV@2AcRQFJDYEVUkL8RJSxczzGupGQIL8Y@IpjA9oScGqtzi7HAxdqHNmvBAgEZBVs5OSAsH45PzXPJt3rBW2jIwYSsdaBrmR2xmJVgMaf14baOqrGF6gKyn8cqYrMi/EJ9A3mJVcsUNEP5hoear01H5VICScQA59Xl5KIR/Xd5gy9N@tYvkrATVDZuTRqA/pnfk89FEQpXycIKu2NmsqBYHXgcNiz3ZNPan5d5J7ptmlXFhwsp6Nb5LyJwcUg7uODB0e7R19vLYFhme3KdYe0mSsVsKmdTOW@PUnnFK2yGYUxB/ywtR42RlwMIwq@N5OdaURVmnWgcZkG5Dw8@vQ6SUATQnJQCmDG3zWVhocBpUto697gWiPM@skkJBlGCcIy@YAFMEMDoo7@eoDPs8mbN1h415Ea@e6ImTXROYDAMX1gB/EU9LymgAVe7R5vESkuaKGmjeOfc1M0ZIDPx6g1X0eGVOkIy3x8@Gj/qEZgB7p3ZliWTEHS3hh0Kd3tKsDz1qRrCMvCgPgDU4cllTniqE8TrksJ3OksEHhetmwFfACAXRzFYbI1DLLmDQD3vet5I1e5E3IA2QnCdb0yqg91PhTRCB7YxHWwp7usFSWPeWMVOi1tsULfxWark88bxVw52mx15ml2o0CHpBSbTqA3uuB15snoosy1SF@t9tE/fnwDcY@USOgKyAFmnsUUSsuzBOy9yCaLe@k96KE5lqG8IIknMlFKp@PBwKfS8ajPGQm/PzXHiYzEv6oEYSH13d0D7WEQ2B@oowEM6jRgFxxbJreHEw0dD3jEdiyn77AtiMO1wyBBUJtWZnO379g3SkhHR8xqDGcuQP7ieI0@grbGfEMdR4oV7a7yWQ/d9i5ASquFLBKJKESg0hReeaWf60Cueb6PD76xD42Ims9kQnOGHiBBJA6RC02diCs5MBkSUnx8lmYwnMW4UdsDDzkyjYCZ9gVdGHF37r3UkSSmkl4afilKX3VuUPyVM7vGWuDCWQsMEZIdPH32@ODp/pPdz0/HWj6/YM9lygUgHKTXBl1IGXC6YW3d4lUTs4XgYlA3XKxeIAUm0EEJhsMnnguCW8EgCkdgBdfw@Z/EV52BHfek65m5QF/5ld3hLPQEKx8P6keEjnbXws6Iy6fNsD1H/hmMxyOvkk5DLR9M2gp0WtOvOo6l99MUDxoGy0qr2HU5OMRxDW9ZDEDGmxk8Bh/TAtVhRgOHujV0oPNCU3EoGliCg6fBKsvsD6AvjPN1hispIQdTbtJd6CFAXzkd5o0EMNmAtv43KCeRs/ZXVK3E@VrNaLm0GARbqP4QdqNnQNcpAa0VkEK6ZmWn907vsRlIaYR0HUiMKVv@lA22BRYDRZIGS7GfHxCHpAUOk6KsIBq9nuAgLkipdD6TK6qFfBq6ZdBNA51VxqE2eaiPOwN57MgAT3Z6NG4Q4cKe19HtnrLlGwJkQe/7CLKabXxxemo3QUE/vUe44URYY9ZsqE2pym5G2fLDS1Xg3oXsIe8GDsC7ZATWpC9bIc@6@k1x1tWpdnVZejwc@W2OPGJPdkGReuOAvO4a0bqHEdJRz/TWQtg0Bn6XXjIgZGFUAV9IqTRUKGhpgfXSiJcMSi@qh8A5ILciEdh8NIPng08/R@QIdrqR700n7tFYPeo1OEjqjYCINMbcQSnt4fjgGFrHkPNRSkPhopBmF0Ych891jw9SQiR/0jGID321EAINxocD0XY42QpMQLGoew6SA/gKR0sH81FG7PQDp0GChBMOPoAGYdOkQR/kDETmGdnlGeEpkctils5s58JGaG2DleS2OeZj/M7Exck8sxvNGwTPajwMQKPMReQ6zfq1jQ4fZeWRKRfQCdTZ0Bg6OJQA2hWJAoOyoPMZQ@wLejhQDdUqI@PECcCX2f09kGIdg48XyUPsRAFL7bP42E3vyt9I6/Ib4OY1uhVmfjc6gU2FfhIQgEYiwxlsGiXxR0BJO3GGFOgFjbeg54NA3RVGs/EAcgwcJuo1Z2TY1/t8vEeYkKo0zxqPg8A37cRlfGNjI16J1@MpMO2AaRtNO2hKgmmHTDKZMJyCJoqRIhP6NigGujXjV40A8lRqIg9MUXN4Y44SeqNSyTZTekP1vxp@JSgKoDyElvEDcOJSrYZGSRLrFzhVA/p7JO97yDvHHdcc@ST4KigE3O7TIEtEgO49avOuUcW@6XqKDGsudBoNVDETbvy0kTltnl6edpOnV/EUxpaqeg36hyC8xomh0nedyQgUt0auIoNskxrZSrParsUz8a1EoiRbkJAuSR@VpKTOaZ2IG8BTidPTOJDUp06jM3AJ3jSlSVJIKMCjZ0Ivw7ISceWyBOm3paaUjENcKZ4CsVyLx4EuHSSCR5nGEQHORI/MKZASKiY0cdE5BRKQNCeF1fUbxmgwc6MBwlE30LJxBH0@GQ@VgaR4VEq@4fGjCt1CTz/Qe3k4UG5x8A71pdGMS3eBY3qaXlgYErS753Jv6Iz19GcKdJqUSHMZ34inZRlaQvLhkCjbT0wPq7BuG87Ei440Lh0AxdTB9WQwAWEZrJpJAVeZI8HoDBwW37wP0Fk4zYNNCc5YyXzeKwDQ7SjwQyGKWglOloB2QctJTJCLuNSEj8qohAQXPcHYfL4weq2EqVUpDstgQmbfdlxDBpJADIEWf9BSIaHO/BUlBzTydWNewvelJg073qYBEvGR5ehEWy6uI/NBo2EkPvTPIcqR0RUskB89EI8KLwvX6Ka3BJqcddwBtBCQG5TEWlhaQ98j7XijrjKeQlQhgQ1u1JP37kDpvGBdTdMKnXyvEvghVwCxB1BI2Cu1oYsbeMkqeEp@Ie/zYaGgj/708OE@HzuhxhabVxxHaw2d7gT0Sr/fdGTY/RTbB34ybWdoAhmC@G/OrCPHGfNePlhWjczwTrM5nFg6jflcH5ZZG6/jtB2LhoLWRZ2Hn7iebul8ECrw3f3sCej6z0@Oa0olEiitnw/Xpo3jkMuT5fQ8iM450jRrMD3kccYUN/MitlvBYjQUM75HAT0m/lI0KKPAvYjuQZXCORTfvYTuQ1yGBrqyP4pA1tDRD1imgLg0DVf0@I6XauYK3Vf2wcJwKoXjiuMc20tVI/fzca@34Jwl5zMZRZM1d86RM1@ittBHjKKU54FwvdpCmCigAoUJl61dD@cLr3CJwcCwghnEI1BMcJYM2nYL1Sfom6AmzteOGaBIj3AyhCQ0TrGxDuia3o1hC6hTI5mHFmIbVE@gDUuj5iJsppk/xF2lmmI7/tSkx6WnA117Gj3ZrvMJa@w6ubzXluaD75stALFdrwariVYFw5Ti8TAYQSXcIAZlk6btb2Q1XITh0Zi6QFGqgpeGXsNUy8in0@J@M@0REXpMPD2dfpTRPofOB6752ryX7htVTG4ltcjOx6E7AxAbLDldJBmUw8TuOVZX5pNeUP6Md5ewIPylBuGqMxL44GK6wYIzExex@AsDQVxG1qrdgHut6Oo3A0RWt4WAoDZcsrdnqfO3rAEt2LnijSxz3GRXythpDTDz44lrX18Hx1VK19VnnuCvVKmx3aOPP2tkmhyCMNRxIqvES2saLKMEPRj0HlytCiZcbzM2x9Sw08ICE/OrKoDUlOY8AH2AwROosjAhP0eI@lvj7TwvPQM6ngkDMfdmwxQzpCulZ@njsWFz3uKziavJzad9/GRqlPyOP4dQYRmaaAFF00Q/QLHKjk8e7h8dKcChXiK@jxMyFah2emcA@saqTAeUjGa@wj7qxtlHGEfCXrgAVQo6Ey0/PjBvFZgbuhOQOoqCvuEmwFHCuZQOONP0FUXkCpdPIFw11RkTjUJgCUOCPBGwylL8n9u85@TjWWFxliRKArkT9ypAW1NSJrb5WvGg3SA1FILEed@TlsjWNhMkvjZVifjHNYc4FwxdJtICIQ@NBtsA6UahRVZ7x75oZORyM7nJms0qn@GHiKjT05Jbf/mm7tOTT4eRgPRxPvB7Zb1ri3iDFGjkFmNx/FTgWcHnW0DWnbRnN2upuKmJUois/AYcuKd4Hckli0w5isHSJhIhtBJqcUXT4nqpSLaeUyf72uJwyE6AQJgfnIZM8FyyjRpTJSnAjAN6obvYda6wZ47nmW2LVq/2LJOvBAsb64pPGB9SQJloclWsGEQ3rM9Qz7Aw5kuW@UJgnxLkTw0N9KQwZ@SQkNglEpNIqSEV2du36CCyTY0RG4i4YpjT9yro04J8fOwAso/9FdBRnYOEhr88BUXHqSAGnbfF@V/04R2D9Pk1nVc@F6PxuM5p2mcOzSKFplZGUfOoZ4axh2fWzZg90xvQayFoiAMPq63Czhu2e/RaEoAmU/xpenKgYXpfw4bi1NNH9KER@yUpLy5NWUi2bfQmdp/mNNHM5Ne3hJTLJQrca7fNVUGBCLjaLPguCQayEmuepuQUNag9OMADzSLIT94nmmf9@qomtkB3aKTGEMv//pdvdoH@N0tnAO0VjmeGhhZoClhScm9lYflR0UKv5QXLh90nlqkTYch0G8iO7kKWdCs0LAdNU/uyDPrGECcq/BIH3sQX6KJr2IxjzucZg@/yRJZN1dkgtzurwl5b5cWTokkl6C52iQhc5zINikRClheCMeUTO5GOOwrc25EKlmIxYmZe7oPJeMLfoA7fWojmCH/r6qYfMpPX26oBHVK9bRpritzVzyZdRx6d9UO1uLAk7Dz3NLMsg1biTzK30Lg8@zyDrtmH5j74rgo2b1/TF/S5jSs8e@KN5Db17bvcRhVhuCYF1@LvVUFMf6dSaFhNNdOi1x050YcOjOKvsUjjClY5QjTzGpktvT1DVWjw4VwWrlcAiVPrJJOZ7IoJ69FodXzsn1L8cnl57KnS4fRYNvKQ5qtkZT42Rxn2183eUqrQXJlD3ZK1bsS4UpgvW@5wI2g4U0pxjHOcJzpfWnJz6mOD1JlYujs3rWHxOR7B5MSqcW6/2fDrcsexTA8rtLVKagZr7uZp4TplekXWVZjLKNmFjii243JoWi4FnM4Y16KuYKs7yDS@BhRX2kb4RHFWEavjXOBvpQYxgM4wfy9v1N4sxeoO8km2OpYOTfnKFmFh1BFHNW/h1QvTM@i1nLBnSxEdd6yl7ou1IBhPjI4P3sbZnmk5Hjum9zoC9V2gAn8v5@koLU3dlmmUPWpeI4aCxRPzAtWtvmMVSv20Dq@VpT5xeyj6/e9dhVwopFT1FiEVaECOrfrflaL9LO2e3VZAtP/LxYWzEeOaVnaZpPIndVbnDvoGOCO4PGePMiWKqaT5GOKKhHEu50KfBd9foPVYRdqg9RjNSKMGBQ8jlEtgGLtcy/5FUsutT617N6F0A2zxtkxECvfMMqC9oveNImVaRv3AGGomc3cR1bMmxsRY2tc4bL8ycBvxmn7G3ZHK@NnY9KcAcNYB97yEod74ncM7YY1NNdrWChMdeu3G7drMolAbgQI@wt7zMzA8Q8PNGH17Mloo1YUOmn20nmSDUVClne4CdujzoXKodIuytKCiewb91naaeCcPV57VcplMxtdhIlM5C5Z1nalsGPeVyd8LCZPLPOV5WJy@cyPG5WkQWaJrG1eKIG1V354Cl8tp27SN8Qzfd5SmbcexPqSkQKh2TdTGQLmkNbzrSuyGuuPvTmHz0QsPxzzavVXjFry18buXQB/sN68r9Ohc051KU8bZ1CHOdC1a14/gRGaubksFt3PjsBBf1Wut1iX9ARFVKSnFtbWOa6hO27B0/pkWcuvglZXsWniLQsOfBcZZYz5XPJ/jj10TSqMZEMvsQkdlYAwNsq5R9PXuq4kXfFYGmjr4W@U9NYxOerpvdFYFGJkgF2x8L0xOR5SlsWNDF2uMCwixq2LhElXfdZUEDqYTlxL5YKj3DX5GxTpJOR@zwGU6vGc3Ny4fvajwpTkdiDYfYV7NElCpzoyZF3yXAnwy60C5Toa3j7hdq/wdHAa9Q21ftTb2ZhNrD5yBPTAGfEF6aFtVOYAfx/xMkXWoA9b9Aa6RG40W1s5H6Wk5lnUXeqJo5ILScXpLcdrHXbW4JeyD4M70Nnj4n1vH7/Qxlx1oWFlrBsYE2iXPGTsjQybbqqAWjvXw9yoZGsx@/6KDSGu7@kCR4PuLwr@1b9nXnfFoRJ/WyJp49KKoMm2Gvk1v6vE1L7Ta0nH7yhtn2FZ8R8VfEEOT7stFTNscdwa4CZ1zttF32p2BeRvSbUMf2@ZZOhj14dY79V2RMiaTH6KzYplAXnemIL/Uov7H@DlYVej@ABJv1kLDGn1l2SAd7feWR/pZx@MDomhiFRwTjtRGviu8QtvpK68n5ngONLJIKhzh5TMTaFiFu78sY6VmRZsv5mLYX66xkktJSUeFXDYyoPCoK8eXFhbQRapYNstfqxCK5pIwiix4@RBy@4uKaIDQjAzdgvsCfy2shlrayNmDSd@7KTD5iH0XVDR8rR62oEXSkVFraLN02/@sIrNmpXH3JHxboHNNjLXTKvm18yoUTrVk3THh04IPFN1k5RiaZY48/mZyb@VsnL9ICvri16cMOW1myzvTfsF0jR6fBUHTbSri0KF5WtBB5A7O6eMgOgpzrnhxwWU7fRDqssXmgYOwq9SWpeuPlhd/2GbKnz81@jou4n5sjnEV6BKuIJZdtm7pVthfm@ie@bUJ5GwVs@FREHwm0o2eGYC2JfCe6H2z88lCQYRI@gT2l5DyzwL7o9PNsrgYmB6uoQoNawamkOU4EyPXtaDfsCTk9aH78BSMeQXi@yuXhl42vO6MZrgNbUamdSPr5phGWf3vqq7jqtVla5G4mAxHE8//LMeBVmlFR6GHZ@TuXZgAXH4NopUNdGu8fKQ6MuQKWpjfKM6Nq7Txb5iW02ffKGUYKG2ghKFyvoRxHkDz/AyXBrn2Ek6ktO8484kDHbLLM/YaytbIMtm0zfH60ZzxGJcJBV/MDG85cOtD@jG@lfsfCkE@WU6Rx7fr@vM9z7e078B5x87E7RhoDA8yiXYL/FSNvWBZM24VcfAglotoL23t7A00h449GcvuxF7bKhTWtgoVNi0VImzAEl/bf/JcinIDLQO/TQs1oPM38azZ3LRyzcA1JjNtUMRWy9HF0EFf4iE/d@mI1iDfEmcXD4fqkLh@6Czr7zybucb4zh0mEP6T4UOjgzOHt6b91Hni2A60RiMQlMMjgx8msLDWY3lEjPYYt8sDfbq3JnNMYFc0Qlzb0EdGG8rXmpvu0hZxwA/1sb6iKaKxQer/haZbecW02ob7igb9IuZVXdpFhD4xptS3WM0wvA7K406Hq8Q4HrdQRxZmbLyR49j8TdI2Ax/1yXqpAk0Bve4@V67gCv@FcYGl/bPFrB6e84UiRpefdrEqr67Rdiz@XrMsyTb5sgDdNQ0v/RgPTyC3Qo7JoH15a2VIca0MmXeNQJM91z2ap1/e1ZiDVKcfsApooLsdB2fCfMOaBTqREw9uEdPhpgG@dqANhJ@CxNI7E//sxdvQsobtIb1WdhgipXlktHG7UZuOCRnr05uFyUeG/DMSIou6wpMFAnGFlbrAEs@gNyLd3mwt9KMWqWqO6EWSeuV0Oa3XkW3T6LzRcdTMIXrNx6YX/CHP6adkXDFWHalGNIqc1mkL/dKatLh6DRQay5DHAxf6/OnxuuHt4PyWJfMhk6GBk8yLszArVVfHG1BmneXz6aFwdQ3ZPzsQZEl4jiDXD@XdlZongof/wwdfTUMj3CrkgjNNQHTdPoMPyE9c2//chQOfOd64Z04PAW/cd7BKnGC28hAFPrxmoGlrVSag9OyJxUcf@pGlV8MudcdkOr9Wli0S12NDNuxzmU6Ym97MkcN3k6V38TDUsdGV/QMWcKZBfhxsLAuD@d8lE6hR2YjrPdU0J@y0kPNXgC4j7kUgGUDfcsbyyKNveuQ9O3h8eKKMPHVp@7Q7wP0YN/S4hRMbtFImMiT1Sncj8518RVrX9MbpB8eqvPf4QMEAK@jNZzRk@ODM3MJn5binf/SontZX9oLQ1xgvVxA/OXnyODnf@8kSewPXGRpS1Hvv@DiFe1u@erzUOxr7EdSOnjNdGf1gX1WlJez73KbZwVXSc0lKqyCdGNAbBWb8hB/4cqty1XFGRvdkNjI@g8YTJbh3x@QLKzP5VD83@1gLWXkloaiisrJSyEmRxdnQ2Tbc8LuqPM/MEUrLDn3S/LNyOQpqDtm0m12uPayb8b@uxbCMvxLhwyKpmZvcOjZlqBn9AZrSuvf3RUxV1VV0PtZ7UK4sv7KwFgMsmx@2nPM7TCUbfudFDp3kMXCVbN66lLwoD0F0p/GFw/O@IxjbK5fBrAMQOheWVvgLw57ptkxzWevUiwrExkVta4N8w7jDhFS4wuccD4ReOscXrqpniQ4ZpVsSPnEjUfb2HhzcFuHIp@X6UB8/fc6e6R6ebrI@YBRj4w4YzzWjVzKOW@HReiunU7sugNLWwuuPltfnCjvW3a5jz6a3T8LR5lZs2umw4hAW2iiQYZlTc1lb1eHjWs@WLzO6LW2@j8OZLejB0VNvfEDvv/PPVDWToTON8KtmuPWWkgkqOEugSZ/hQXlRr5ODUDR0UG9RwEFa2ht9bExxOQofDV7WqV/avhXWtH1FaXVzss6vtMYvtya9G37oyLJKRl0DML/Gj@WV0PuxY10MHGVPdw3vjmUSQW1dlsprssT9@Naoo4kdPazXS/nHLfAdjXyPmacEJyonEnYyKUmLh/ZHd9TxvWR4pBvfBgZh375lG/5uL/AIN8D5e8zw5CdQPQ3cmSkQCNz6l7BrNTVfZjt4dH4FGhaJUkQnOl8nSKvBNi/9rVuVinqF29fEisj8rXXhcZn8yEeAi4fVQZ6YfKayzTH4bAYbvxgdWs7eMlJWoXVU8xmwKenoTtyqvyMOUNq8fHbwbP/4ZPfk@XEj07wSJX/fJ8fNtiG1YEfwR9muCHn3yQaVgB8ASztHLUiODlRHJdcL8sUgZ9eyVlvI2jxT4g7G2by07XSaNkCm5SvATxZ5auQLLRo6cdhBjql8/P2rFb5v0CKSipsctEhpQplVWGZZwiPd8yBbvv/1Kx3Il2Wz6MsT9s/sBDbvO07XT9Ez2O1PkOKj3YPHz4/2WYDgnGkuzO54UCvn@ZGu2FDIBpRTz6S1FDUW96PEoaxqtfijOBAmrsRZhbad0nGqwOcQLKAOblj1Y2@xxCbBBwrGw0JJ/5dvpq/iCi4LlCBsPEAqznzKYwB2glvJ/uwnXX7ceHCARHBviTskqUgb9QV/m@iKTaJIUaqYo9W3l9Dx3rQfNDxXfH4jjECnzQNXXtDZT9fOBZLoqA5@FY1/bFOQEDFIcEQxji/hEUzQOT43cTMox6GHJyItsjJOSdMpYArbxatZgOeZTkfeA@oTe8xPHfHPKIgBHymhQEmxTUKWH5AvRgLGtzeAldtG37SZZ4PSbowr7BXwGY7hVPiOZFmux29ECUDzO3nkwXhoRQLeOELJS5@O0@9/7bvpfpWBeZp5ALZf8W09MP8qN3@RxrK@eczSPP0oEng0mo81TzykOdI7cguNzXd@z4mFp0EFkpKZQyiac6I0Bucp8LcMAnYOJ9H4DAoKWAxKyd/xzdMz3GYCz2arpNPIRjgfptAqV2PKl5xcO6OtkC/k1DQgKZ8HAOlQ5T5up@MAJakCjC@cm6Payzaw1/Y2E1EHNGqFKi/N9Kb9RVZ8GSK6CWGFiwEi12AQB6LMY4Bf3Y8GzUlSlTAqyqO4GkdR1HWgnSF/bI/QbvuEEFkCiMVpZOApvVO8jmjszoKzBtt4xU/kwP1NH5CsQitDJkkU/E3KT50xsMzC9my@SRmXXPE2DQ/x8vh1W3TEH/KgcrM2zffWBSf7@/VLwXrPQWUz15vHaNmKLxDEMYKoiMtYtvEFOx2f2s00500GbPojn2WjzGyD@Z@k@yt4lud79@YBb4nrx7Mhsdj9Y9tBZfcRZIYltLSWTasFaZ6lXG5plvwc@clAdvDYibeQHIgmEBMdw3zljLzdvf2Drx4@O75xiBmFjF8PBpK8vp08lZVUoxka4tFsLRbJg0fp4ycPHgUFMUe6EJHAoL34OVHX5WTeh0WQ8zXR17O2DMPruVuN8Qu@cfI6vlltHWoU6QYeauYD0qV1ifIj2l1wPXGttIxa@fw6lObw0hHQe3xr2A1UE9LlVaO5XT@1Y/GbnLCkInwRU7awEoDp1NvaTCOz38wcZiy8Fu8EL/TxonUxu7wuiptZPEsHN6eOnbP5KUK@Q8Qjkt8gGRCRgpIOgq6sfYdc656fdaXxa/v4qTvRs0YiCBcy6ygeAXUS3ACIUmR@Up9/SN0AepKW2RaCM174YXXBmVrhOXX8fJaEJPjnvfOEE/6dgNPKVKFFCAkJpR3BSrF1594F8CQBKjTqa88m0KN95oz4@b802fTQCExHDojfhxM@a22wr06GEK5HnyODBv5AcssQGSgZD1Hl@hNICf/Yu2kSDxaE9Bp4@J2fcWXYzSemkjIwpl2zD7I9IaVAon2kqk0WHo2Hmaaj8Oy4SGU2L4W1VfFj3PAXJfsHnY84nSOgN3TFtLvGNBG/iEuVJqSP7vGLF@dxSVzGS3ROo39wYff6gY0h@kV1vSTRx37tDE5DXCYtyuWbUgLcrgPmJw0Fl4@Uy8rAE@gOqRrq4sdj9zEYQY1I9Ib6iCUmNj@NSWFkTZwm7BQdXyPX@YFuNksmqYsEH/JQGMXskYm33wndnrFEugZMgK6e3cXPG3PEGqqiNMFMiUhsEy8F2gONC082kQTo1UKUCoGtIQtBxwEw4pVE4QwOcdBfwANnXDrTaok33ZFC4yMO0oRyzer3WORup0XNUSyXK36BLkrFMgPuuykOlTSAvSHnAl0eqOufnAA0gw6tIsTmgvymxItRujGOyCf@kQuATixyCGNwEgMDWPMjEjsDF3@JfRvqCh4eU3l@8qhVktIiC49u6LtmF8fv@DnCYafNv/kBqml6IWi8yvtoH2M0PJOrxc@GwCOjHlGFEa@J1FiUDNdvOp3zpqqu5Xo/ol8KEDKHDYC/v6UVgMPD54KZ1CV@y4X9z3@Od6mKic2dQrZlnSfj@UwVXmo1z/Lso81TWd5saPlM7f5mU9fHpyLT07mth@fGoNc@6KdPRZFlWS6d3tIKr89GamHri4byetoUG6Va6qz57Iw9e/b5u9Y7SZyez8TTBCvG2N7hW1GFDMQqRVZm@Fv60CWHS581vXQxDnBPT/GOVLEoptONeBP@yeslPDxQo67UlZ3mu3dSowh5ms5OY3j1IDu8T97UT6KRJk2Tjk3TTLPTkdftws8ZsCa/PDfGn2QyITPfQW5wNzac9shtumv0@5N9fcbdzdgEP4/Gftwn33jx4gUaXtDD3hz58Tl0FqRRaen5GNMy2p/9dOMqdfmstf1n3xqmjQ38HOLnu1dP0Hys5j/a2PjowYNcLgVU4uZn33j29d3d3dzDVP5ZI7@TkzMb23/6JxsbmratpTeanqc2442zs89FLZMTlT/7cbz17NnXPA@LBZ8sU8GI7xL8VNSpztgbeM56DP/J/KYbMetobvfeMC32JgZsHZvRXyvGeC2skZYUfTaYWt8p/tfvH76OjWN1Lf3Che849jpWKMW4EQxgywa281g9to3BClexWbpWq4Gx@F//HcSvfxXgoM9sG171fACrMIvV5RpFeRurF8Cgahqk@39985u3DPvcZw14xFxRE3ea8GzRsy3ggVlyJp2@Flwt3VPvMWaPB2PDwY/JPzZ8mF61odd91Egmk01FhkdpUaS0qmqnNGATZS0ab4mFzlXGXVjEbc4nvgv4vYgRTwFTEV9xs@9ArMYdXlwP92LJU33xD/0cCbHCxn3jYb0OojBbz27Vk/RsnFYqnPxpViyJjnNf3IIiy9DrMYMPCMy6yFimpImpVOp@C7RKDWkqT336xeKnYjwWezknaUDZGJvbWNQp5pOShXXwFwi3j8@f/29//oM//z79/YB@/xHPFrO7Zi@9xfAabXZe5w@r18W6K16ekuU@y1RKlVK6xa5OE1uNevOIqZmP38bz2fgxNhIqhTqVghHOWPjU6/gK0EBbPcZd6tw0d/N96qGFQsyjLA/HfMnEmJ8INMH@Eiy5cQ4yth7kaHrjYY37UEiiViyLzbqW1w7rYkYVqdjKbLDpMSfm52gHng34o394dnDw2HfB9wY5ch8KuuTZCFG5/VmovUKs0Ug3jSYosqweALm/UdkoVQoVDQplNeDqKtCx86g0UYpKSdFAfLxrbLAjzutNlgye0@Stz3NFaflGMjj4k2VnGhNi/wBPXWCxS3ia77Ya74B1/aQbfj1NbsvNetLHCD5K634zKV9dNZQvktWq/79dD41VergJMtK8kuXtLwBW4yZUDpTeSuuLbQCb3G5s15w9@iktJLEczznxgnO/@UW9sb0Iwody/34SRe19gFPfBCaVkslNWd5orMwDAG4mQAnYhgK82r6qXzW2r662t@F/m95X/hdcr7Zv/NNn/qwIM/enanPaSNdP06c@2zTBrqTr6KKkT8FQhy@Eg2ZIiIFiMhViW2wrNmJqMQsmZlTULS2bzk8/KuyDatRoytiDqckNtZBvylxSvVRYReYHkqulgqSgKGo5vRbuIVTYSyH28v2X/wv@Tt9/@fvY7kO1LAux9BZ2D8q8lwCvJzZ78uQJ/p7YNvzD7wl/bHRBhyfoZvOXzUMEYUJn7oLVAYQCE7VSQWwl1ZnGYttioYhi4ZduPPF4/B@91MrFOO9B4167lx44/tKy5x/90qpHiL0tYz3veIznSYhRvYeygPpTl@X69hCXWOHItIydgM9qU/n5roy9Vn1Mcw0d3iOrHezXyuW656G6KMQuEUr7Nf49foN/r8f4d9LBv6PX@MdO3uDf0Rj/2JM2/j3z8O/kNf7ttvHvZIh/D17j35Mx/j3v458Qq4GOvrmTsTKdjHqmnoHBZBmXZQaZgdrFDkTGYJlZZsYyQ0ftgsmAvwyYzEyPZfosY2dsVQVPMIxZZoymHnz68NcDKC78mThJf6ZmOgxSsbDBoZuI6PsW5J90KjSg5ym@NECbVlQloxTMJh7g3hCbWrnEFCwYpdV4eRpv4smgWjnH2jNj4/Qli3mgiVdj6dPTNB9TYFquime9X121WvtPH7ZaaZRgp0@cw/n/4eEwal37Pzx0nhw6Qwf@Dw8PnzCjnryflO/DU6snt/3PTqxe3TmtyFjdAwkTS2/vnNazMpoLSZAWGrolP/CZQ4RvfeNUiDNQcC6qpEZVL86rF1UyhFYwtKphAD8YN4Bj1Ve/wKUa6GEX8JxfkCO@0Hjx4jQ0cUP6xcUpdiegnxj@g54atf43@Df/3/X/5DlLNJqgFiUur7YT9Ej4J0mXV5dX/rsuJRK@JbENf@gAdoxyeVVHIwW6BFMjITWlqyvuBu@EtM0B1jGN7TpFngeE2h8L06R0@Svx3/aLafvPKZ4hrs8n@E9Pp5mMVG0HZxbj5Jb@luZZpSrdQLPZbqjNP/0xnUy9I1GgfK5aVbcYt2g5rVrNBbZiqVotBZbNRKJ886lndtQC6EW5nCRVq2DZCcBmwBqCLQHYwJIHqIand6jeV2OXB4d0ZjOIiXxMwhxxwZDI0NHueEtIXKyI9@4l/NtHd3ale/e0cubt29BlNAIndcGp1eqabquF7tm3b8WWSBPu5TzYM6W3b0GWxSXHTTzFy2UgoYSsso@0OqVZdlwgRBG8mZrW5lgMdE8fj93EG3OUEnG5kSdKdPdDJuO4p/Gffe9b3zqN12qiLJJrTkUAmArLb28XcvV6IQfmQgkoJW5e8mtQ@smyKl1tpkVODSZuxmO@l1oqSlw2xtEfGka2U4cK7uHDLq9iVOwsl5cSIF0l0M@uYvjHndVymbuzXCFRSpb9v9qGxOqgOvA/7NZmk7mt4tb9JqO/6bIHRXL10qipV7VLo4Kjg1fVjn@zH@5PNO7dy5aBpqVM9VRotR7unuy2WjVRFLE9hBc6knAX8EKhkRtvUIHny80G5q95Go9XqveJOdRSnsXiVT@cHIdWgpXKRAbB7OHmY8i7oPpjBhuCRl98Cf4Q0gY4xrBFhx//PHu8u7d/ktK2QRHSHu3upbTj5w9iKlrzczt5Z9F@tL/78PA5RHj2eH/3eP/jg8/2nz8Dd49dzJ9AAPvv@TdqWmK/YC@EV@4b3TB0Y2IYrYvJ5OI1e2WaLRPoak1M03T6LvOMlmEYIwgWPFX4dUxPf/VKd0f0sPc/@s77H/1373/ne@9/5zvvf@cHP/vyB9@B30/g9z3@/d6/Lefx/bMv/9nvvv/t3wHH/wi/P4LfT3/25W9@k//I/sfw@88Rtz/2f5Fw/CcArF/52Zff//HPvvzVH8LvX/q/H978/dpPl/9@8O3VP4z3/d9dH@Z7/w5@v8dhBWG/99vcDb83wv82D/erP3z/G/@e//@p/4fG33n/G3@ML9/yT3/4p//5/bf@g6aV/vTfvP/2999/@1vvv/3d99/@x9r73/w3aib6@t33P/iDv/rD3/urP/yf6P8n9P69u/y//@E//Yv/9S/@97/4Q//3U/j9ezD99C/@AzDs3/7Bj/D/@3/wt3/0I/z/n//V3/7Br//tr/xrMvwWN/zf//Lf8vdf/9p/@pt/8d2/@uk3/@bXf/o3v/UHf/V//Or/@Zv/6a//@9//6//xW@j4Wz/9qz/6lb/81nf@8tv//C@/9eWK93fWvr@8g/uX/wAud8fzLnDukq8PdfnyF8Ln70ONeSrAJ8Dd/@T9b/4yMPhvMPb@Oz/BRbbwW/H/E02lMD/htv8PGLSbeUafDJjg9@vvv/M9JNH/ACSC/5Be3w0tCz7c8t25Bcj6L65FihmVxbazpJWSW9DB2CqX/fYz9N6mmD/78p//OEzilxehLvhBit9FSbXg912Uce9/9M33P/7H73/0W@9/9CvYmsm5cmo3Javrh6yhBZTzdwiHAQt3CQcBP/8c0p8maYBVTqKNfe57fv7558L0bRpXdd9/C66fkxN/GPcCP@Z7BX6@O65vjYbhxkxg3ETnt9GkkQxJTDZJmsBWoKbks2ya9DGa4vgdfsEdAk23yDjFN7mi91TA1/x/bpwKLIlh/JHL5NxIBj@enwQ3CnlIJjmdBvQivYlxXWWLu9DcE6WbKzPMwXSanEKHFAyQQhK8HiRZrVZLYsQaxwesHLV6iREqyWQN8o2xeZxUq4Qgpg8ICsSsJY9Ya6s25RGTCK8ekCMpoNORqGpislR7CAnWpg8ZwkLgBPbly1q9VJvWEdw7To/kNPmAcEJgteS0/g7sNYKZxKGoh@8AlVItmayXMEHMJC@eVIsXUp4yR3lPsqRfBvClcd37jH0kqiWRz4NsIMF4aHwn56F3aGZuB/xPk1t@dug/MNJviwi@QUn5qTDuv0Oa4g5XHjEAwJVlRVEY/HC2b4fdB@8pB5WkZOGT5BCSxBHEAaEDsCGWRZLKN0kWSD9W2/rgJ1kXeG42NzeFWF3Mioc0L5SETrt7VuE3mbzlPaMKEwtlEZ0NWi/Oc2dsPqNRh62HW/BW4X9/g5ZxJ1mV0NqM45BgnPH02EdJ/rt/f4t9BLmn79xNYHIy6@RwSB4zup1MihqkWneSwhcg3QRgXwL0VlCmNZqNSgqpFGNKLYZ@7PDw0EeNHL6oCUngfi2roh2nDyaTSQxiKEpKSaX8r0JfclB8g0K@/lfZRJrTECbTtFwVujdVhk4s2htRoduKju/evYPCoqUclQPoUDJ/VYeWK5EnOPDNrpY1C3YbaLmywHvTTC3wu8YTdBWhxCSBJdiWJPBFvxyJ4EnEtVIpjiYJykRJbAWLfAqqEIwsxuqIaPDwLl4pLwWee4ds7/DJk/2nJ6NmkwkG3RFptEau0zE8b51gTmC83acP@Z4ArVxANGKNBqZ8UtFQLAn7lQwJzYOHRwfHFcZp4pdQIoQkVWnU2CdFWRVio9GL7Zi/EELES0sc8RjflXn@E1o5iwnWq0KsY2C3BBgO/1lVeOL1HzhT6MqnRDGlFrCHJtG4KxO@7lQqtXdqrijAl@wThsdr8b24UDtx5biyvU1EE@qXMo2VoxEKuCDU6/6KIqYK9eP9E4hwcshULaMw6Ohf5opaLp/La9lCIV/U1FyhnCvkS1loawqZvKap5VyuXCoXr4T652yqIK4ymK2aZdj98WAT1/GIpxkxQo/NRiaFf1o2C2@AmFLzxebGhnUpI4KnxBaXuCDrCqyXMlLgK/Aw4SsC@wo4wQNp4Cor5i9xOzis@uuM8NSLBF9sJKp5qNyScAqMxMEJo@hTHUH1gb5@5CfENr7xjTGr16GPLR88EmIgpQYsWGsjm11loBAfdSeuQb59xrrmZyZeZaN0TW9k6TOomxlFiF1dXfUA0sEjptU1svIYXXxfdcilDearqS78/88v8sRkuS5sj@rAjNvpERh1MOa20zoY22DMb6fbYDTBWN5Om2Cc1LNqZjs9gTZC2ObnRTHcjloTx8YUj6fjbmLdM6yeglsKaiIloInb/vmLdT9eHfdmOHq3hnsWcU19QroUurWu06G7s4Su0na6M8Ubzyxce285bi0Oqlg88DDxOlLcyVVrsKYyckbQYGr5YrKhZkA@408tpbRUV@lYhu7u5Cv5ElrCiZOdfKZyYdpd50L5/MnjT8bj0ZFBy/t3cuVKV8FDIXD79k6pks83Gw1RTDYomSZexccrp7yxAQxt6F0Zvj3HHnuyVmpC5K7p1mrx@E5WVSvZTEm4CjMvANkwR3UB4yUxJykk3aXP@xXbsaGeVVJ6yrykXFd6vd7V1mVybhH0S5nbgB5XST3VvgytVTkSrsImqaQ59wQXvQfNzKU/Z1QRtXxJrDaqc3uxIFabV8L9odE1dVzSf5q5vBmrAPKIQ41BQqdMuKq4jjOutI2e4xrzgFm1EATkCN0MkBOvwuROM5ji5c3kChgIaMgpB3zKz@aq0zK2BojQ5j60jI3mdnBqF/KnpslaVs6qsprF/1sMGv7fPbwG/xq@IVZWE05w5@pTkKTQVNjsMR4SPnbYiePQfXAPjM6KEHsDndbr7bmO5/09wjzQ7TPu9dDkx0WFXp/oeBGENzTHgxUhno@GuMHScP/BIOwP24AgVWsK8ABeruU4ywIU2fNnK3L5JDygEYjBT2iE4EcHH39yEvme7O/ufSIU2IPDpw@vffJ@oDx7vP/oJLQWuW8QNR@C@Pr@48fXrf4nhkoFjg1vsHwxMKgCLvi9B12qe74xX5gbM2h8wfeimV64AJVvOqwIJ8EGNZ2hsGgbrMP3vGIfj84I8VU9tVgWhBGznQtWzLCuY1k63oXZ2wDHgY4bbwxUXiy6shWTvnBcq3thdo0N4Qnu8SmreOEfIiF8AkCGkw5tyDfHAp441cVbKnEuom1NDDbBm2BXOMIHndDomv0BNAUXThBAaOs6g9@HPhDfiD7j9Q5jnga53fCxbgYXYgLqqPpYj5Wq9@6pz1zg7HopU6n0jbNKfX8KnMWeA6frLsrmzTTbzIvZjviIKa2YvgUaYd9seM0RK0HhZXNbBRW1G1BHQQljqdIRQ40MteWGBhrZaSat5xy7@oY5o7oXz1wZV9DGFJM7OWhExr1OFZuuTr6i1UVXFFi18tf/4ifI1FtpkF8xVRRxLfKGKiikBWvlUr5UzmqlVKlcyuXVQj6fUrUUdDKKZUg1o5bUQilfVlOlXDmbA7USfPPlohDjC73SWwQSvhUAa3fw0rptUqSVQV2I8dkq9iahSyymh/YJEw2II@I15d6YNjtumTVRyzE1w6APBRB11mGxR4/2Mo8eieIDtOAc/V5GFLtoyZcymeIDUTTIZ6@EyoDo8DglPPtDHHNLJvNgTxQnHAAemymKA7TsF3AIRhRNtOztPnqE6fTQomF8CHbGfbjFCixFCGajJZulMRxRfB2Cg3C7PKEcYbqPFkwTfR5xnz3wE8WPA3wyGYBwxMNxCJ8Eed3dFcUDbtndRZ89ynieo/opWnbpEUUXLFBhRLEPhr4LVVUU22DEaiOKHTB1Zjq44RWBeLaiPdZFccYJhCQSxSmF1jtnotgK3DGZTz75RB@Mu0afPzOXfzuAGviY08n@o/bHH7f7/bY7293/@Ah99vY@0Xuzidvut/1o7RY8DsQBn7Ph7PoDOB60Wrq11OdT8LGv@bRmLQNxa@mvASf/6WMiw9Ye@OyBz7KJPg4NniEEbePzYAjfB3qbfIKHfOg7bbfFKjIq6qN0zy/UGbpyNzXUO65TRfu0tsFYPBFPzRqFTLNKHmwImmemekUX/CbwrWOfX7qcNaa1TLM2rRU1vkKklxBPp1reFFMbwx21nK9s6DuqlktOK7jl2enFWVxWd1hCvbf1hiWeSjtaNlcRT3d2ZLGhNnc0tVQpFL/YmoiiVMH3TrZYgYCZOPSI8SU1is2dYj4SpVhM6mmtUixK1Ssgxxia1TZKl1YicWHoZ5KE6GLPDbLArxeeUT7Nai8xTU1rHC82k6rTmlrlx36xzA1YXTxjctIZOy6H2Adw051MhS4wFtVySYT00@mEJIFkIiEC3/mysRdfOzk7OfkcZBb0if0e5TN@K2bVt378yZ4CnUzfhmdDKo9Q73dcZQ8Fy4IPP7owcDoB9Vj5BNpG6BoEbrgNxXUsZX8K/XzsPAQewYlfin9Ok3LyyQKcY@hO85RxF2@VDpawOwbDozPNLtNrdTDpXZYgrJguXVCr3KrXa63akN9BXA9jfcroXMk5mAOP4x7uLabol7g1w/do1TJX1XZtGpsCnFaNyerLodN9qSU71S6emPmg9gAjV1vwbVeNmoE3MYsxsdrbsWuMTWxP7xnPDBd3yh8cboKOgPs1Ej1mSJvslO5t3kMl@kquu8yeY/Z0Mkzocr0tLTpFrEiaxNeCLF/SBiKcOr@q9mos8YVUfQ1Wd5MlusoDaSdX7SYesJYELpmXvZc9prFCrkpX2SUQElQiog3dhyzV6p@CWsMBn1UqgIhfxmcAE1MCsGaXPHRpZF5VOzWLJWQ2ZRKRJ1ft1xoY@y2@tmVRbMpy421TqMvyC6EO9bQ6i@k1b9KmY5ZZpq1qmUJ1Cm5qMVcdQMHqX0yrbm00cY2qBVZ/eIXvk9KrQE6gGoB58zbx/pe/KW3L@Rp3qxKotxZoEi2lVZtWbTy4BViilq2BR7KRy6SgawmvYgoaZA0UgUIqm8ql5CK6QmucyqfAUQV9IGElRMbEVGaaUdSUaqgpqP0vze5LJqXOEqCEEMnAMnb28RpocIFCQq4kK3x1JiW1LYtBKThM35aJTUFSVDFjQPMBG5mpAYI6MnSLYkiSzLJbCWszgWE2Tyaj/UazUtmfjr4GXgn59U4hWcwk30hSNbEh1TzjtVCvCnWUKpTr0QbwrD/yxLzJsAFlPN5Ui1ql0WhjDouZVDaTheyZrbf9bbEuNlOZjYIKJXTFSI9hXGBwXWaujczdWqhK453qTC1rVUGhNRaUoprQyqs22EgCru7zAQojX9ghhVniVAx2Cibi8aIWj0vxKo5Rb4j@0CJIOH49O4ja@D11RwT9SayIZQ0DzAUlbQbLRFWoKwG76ixXFmKXwtXl1Tb0NdO02A40RLZBJlmp3xdiFcZAjzv1jxtJbzD2oWv4ktv1L/j3FBcHA1yBDl4DtZFW1hgmdpDYZ7jxdYfFATHdHTY0LdtsaEVo30BmBkE1Ta3iCHwMlx8rdaC8dwn4bSfruGfkUzab6Uk5oOw9xvrJTYEyHbtO9t3abv9otxrY9nAQ8FQQRbEaF2OX8Vj8Cv6E2H3aqKLxjSosFtmqwhe3dgygz7sYSQy2dxmMAlXw@o@EXuHyodGU3j01rctSVuadfRBYV1exzTSViL/ev/rpSy0PZWQ7wQYA6PTgoAo0Xfk8jmDG0i9H3je0UvbJwaH90H1kML7@v5RrifUYy6gyLqevVnzXPF//K5ZLmqidpWLsfqwaY2dyXK3QHgE2Oi5/Ufyi9MWT54fPDx8JsdONtxsOjm6zgCzsnf3Vr0HAeDYXZ@y0FpvWclV/MVW9LqvbGh7kU2QVEPY9tSBn3tY5@9bJo6CBz/tf/mFuul0CuwbaawWKMJ/U6nV1S2NSbPT@y9/HExwu9z/bfczinj5jf/cnP9aKf/cn/4qWKMWvqh4NpRZjEBKNaqEYu7wcXV5ewcP98rFmjCOVK0pg5sP2amy@DaGS1vWtYjKn3beraT@sWlSlmCfH/MmJYj7mvfW9tEwJvILZA3ISC1gEsf0jM6@p97eRKdRw9xKbT1IbXhm4ovTk5VvGwNKpd/t9UyNTOs0q72S2/U7eZu9w9P2dvMFe1uo4Y6zinqdgvHmrXq8jFBavJ9Nbcablwa9xVW0mGY1YQw/wC2PL3jpd5OjTDVYu2@BueFv@/MbplgedvS2b/owtzwNrYDO2XnlMxBmYdLrbpaNttg2Wr0P5b6UBnVPp/S//pqYV/u5Pfu1t623rcw16buVyQdViP1d//nMIsGazfdDtotF43BWPhrC7xlbcB610oKeIl4T3GA8fdN6wu4Y6g9m3oZOONuEc9RwqmhY/wamboGBbuBc3RVozna8iVQUh1C5JK3b7nRTBYFt4Vj/UTeFS@Ap6QWPKaiAuha/MQYHDEJpPp9PyrIk7orX9CYqnNlPsHkSBFL6Ch2Nt0B5iX@bKIKbSWzejcpQ9ohrpRGxoeB4etQWtiPAViOKfq4ZXEOu43R1DmjYIeQWDEJ7k0W1A2k1I2@IRWuSaoNzzACnGseORbNCcha@AMkBUMEFHYOY2BKiCYPkKEADykPABm022zbISuzSTyer8HK8rXPCM55jpwVZbAaMhtC5u7Q4iVzEcOIHGjjf5IF/4JQzqWcQxAMJh8BnZGuj8GJ1sqHTRXvg7gwJYdO5MgrLG7t2bY1WrmV2JUY4Q/pk5wqEoKgd7Oa4ALOgvfdStiCmGJ6RVA9eQ7YDiSUIXuE7mR6NVI1GZiNYrQYD/OzMtcuS1oiKPKmbALy9eKzpAMoiMZOdl2GHbNaZqRYmFyHcA9w4hRadyhZ3A0@lHivZ54HkFGP48FpyTDdLnJDq85/Pt9b3WDJq9CR5SjCfucGHg75HmZ@qgFDsYB7HDWJAV06LQPdOFDgrNCAcHdCWyqoTR5geaER60hFnLMVxLnJfwQ7EwNIOvjkdR@els0HEaHQcK1Bs5Np1dReds4DJt4AiQUf4RQBztiX2Bh9r7ZUORoxh5dPwPcj5iTGdx0W2AFBenWNsu9GID2qSY0VdYZ9hlWpkliNHoqCI7BCdRJEK4Ddou0rhtGUNA6dgwaJOMV0mn@6AVTdp0XtMTE/hq8MiEpsT20v7Fi@kL88xMn@ChvLLTw700fPd7DBUprH58Ntc/G8lynDNmmWcGH7VNLJwd4DHQ90FpTQFl5z8gbAUHiLVsimXAO8VDwa8InyI3llKRuBuJmXTzm1U3Ei0s0bfUJpkuXqp4rtsR@tLzVvC7uN7MC04foTM0wK6EItfwzx2oxXHLc3ighuCfo1KjIzwUHLkfJaDDGZw/gkbQxY1zhp1VAdsYEJqdYCc/1mLI7VeoAaC6BzULjyIbuxU8fwIwcbuJDlQ9X8Db7COW1QQMyA@H8Q9yARhY9LVF6OAHUTEf3rgLBaPwXWMgV6B2DrvghzufffbD@AF3o5mOiZuzN9vwwWGjQ2nVGK8WgSUfsWDtQH6mrG@AZwEwXILJRkJMAtikKIkcdBj/enTO7QLJkgq7CSnFEIJPaoBCqkJw6yqLnD4vgMcD3ePHYfqHll1cXCh0et7ENRXDwxPZPbxKNj3qm6ATO@mxMRz5d1@ZeOehD3dukvlFDHjB8M6UrvYt35vxryD0vJq/9iIR73lxbBzP8cDx/pBO3cHjbjxiqEcmXVbQSfjLRTj/ac3UZcB/FeQ/uRS/QiCMIZhpapbqpABYqt05S/UuulXf45wqJACHUjQCRzyx0g0sQy8wmaNeGMIZ06aIwN62zmgWEiCJfOh0njTPYRByFlh9@8icQiTbuGC7rqvPEuQvYWhk4MSM1B42g2affMAIzQy75McnmtPGrLkQfRpGh0Yt6PIwF4/UES7XA@VnaaL/lPtPwX/K/afzRINkG9MmV8nQ6Qqzg1yPJ7EFIRHMLAhzxc@dnPsQZFCsmcpBYMjZgtsV/Do1ih3Qm9ugHGsBYwBPjIDgRiLd@OK0cdq0PeNiq5lM94HZRSIElDiAbjSJphfd0IzUt86tkeMtONl4AB@0Sj7e6NQZ@NzAeQXzGBYQMQanl4lnpvWH/tw9Vwj8DAME1MPAE1WD3XHClKrh2a3kCYzTEOc05og1fGSapH35Xr4bqEuc9JywUUDNCCB0D7MEaIIPC2oOv38jkA4vXLxmPAgr05UBQzy7J96MAyWvVRUua6pUSBGsZDlAE8iO6mrtelYCfyiKxjWvSDav/PKPor/xwej3oF4sx54YljcYVSFaVXAxGqgQfnUhqrJ6LVKugEF6S7cMF1qufa6f@q01JLOVDroZPB3MgneBl4omIoXfkXj50DY10RYrISvMajXI4qzGqyWvFwFJOcHDaJ4fbRYwgh@fCxCAkVkazfCjTaPRprUaFxxsuiLaRQTJKSE55VF46OkKJJt@NOg9hbdRY/E0QTvFpW8iwFN5Mwpq0EhkeLMoTlC/wnPFcJbST3Muc4gLfB5CFRv5rNNcmnojgnREaF0DgIx4A0CXX@VVEa4LPFUObaGM4qQMZBS3@WzAZQUwGIngKj97MxEyGfWBQeEXk9QOQN0Vkw1BVGlcF/8y/CemAsfgp950zCyGVBcdM6lrf/8gjk2kbKSCRrQPNZNDgYw9mef@HewLOkcMb70cOKDVtS8clliibIN7Ori@Pd22nHZ6qOOiELzgJ7zUXQr6Dzgnwu6PnLE@dnK5Cu80mcR2y9LnfQazbzt4LnjkzF3Q9bqO4dnxMRRqx@nbpmek8Bp5rrIbtESBHxsuRPVk3@h4guCPQfJuLILmfIWqbquFVw62Wglc0CZVwlWztL4N2TMeF7D/C6ZIfBBPPtDDUcJpvzI6Y@l2mHg8tB/txOycJQ5HvmccEtllIMM6oP@D7wA0GOY5854jHVSLqnR7nKALAwbO0OmD1jfxFAFjXwN/MIeNCOmjEeGSYjp2aSuRQ8KpliQ6KV3yo376wVHZp1pCl8L42iKABWKkmHudxkhZd0lyrZXJ8WhBescfju9xFN/j9fhSL/w6zrxrXuOeH5Z0NjGHAAHnaGRvRwOzDnKrewOdBVRCZ9SreIQ7o9ilRVddxHQXgu76wZUe8EcqtHlgCxH/bBX91xdgEH3/rsWn4z2sxzOQN0NcC5igawO8YHIzAcEPJEmILUkuZO2Hd0wLwuItOo9QhQA1lgSXjWdsQsUcQbfbC09@DwDfwvO4duoG39OCqhr3XIKTe55iZ9rqInrY6hqWPjO6CT9kKgI3yPERdNhIXt0t4yjoSOg5vK@XgLZLCn2hGUei80CVFSyjp84laTVb8SBmyD00Uk4YHqymH/rfEM04xFfjo9XQD4jH8bw3@9zE4c/RbDTjxzhb/AYOX47y9oeXJG7Gv50gQAf/FJvUPFlpnfg8SoRZukOLEIZVFrOMp6wGEPEomJtl@GEkuj2nULiRSLWglIXFKwmWl7i5rsQjXBHwJJ83uhtL3sZ0d@a5CKtxYHMRtvdhTcgNyLgeo9NJRCFyl7Ul5tg3ZAK60TidvaJVaS0RqGFMknRjk7rbpF9IAvaMD@CLA06fwRcB9o1xizNUkDcc0/KvYWHkM9RHEa3FdwElHaBEqMhJ7qMRCSUEZgh@eRWm2VmZZudGmp2FNMMasJhkJJDQWUjSLwUsnnVFYBm98QrpjF7Yd4bPOrENj@3oLo5WXMbNeMVMsfh5vAICOW7EK/sJEMrxbrzykAxevHJMhrN45VMwzOtW/G28ElQLDOCClQz30d0X4WjvxCt7CelKGOtnhhekq8QrYZlCmB1uJYoAKTDfoDXiFJvt@NkcuwY0bKRUphhyjJfC7hONw6Tol4F/fskIXVaAnjjGuUWBWZKpC41GpMXg6UCzERyGvaQmV/zWfP/wEa1nCoNgMkno40XjEHhQw2PxRWHEEUNfmtGALyCIcrOyHCMWacnuiI6fOnAoFfJi@kQ9hfSBboL8GxC4OU@Ebpbx4wfltQiCF@Dd8MTIq/C8gU6QHGGEc7LSErSQqC/jazKFZb2Ii1/60RKise7FQHiRcRCElxKBjch00OFocg4TGzmjRSYhX1wOb0bj0KAcr5TIvdeikVTwa@YKb3L2c4aCIVr5pXXZicRD1BZEEHo2Mk1ey8J2gWQxes1lXURT5ZUPUIjIHKjhRueMbu156BspHBc3KWorVjVDQVyeJEmuRTEJkRU8VWiij3nqYed1H88a@rDuaxBzimMtCQQQiRmmwuWr8wH6u8P190ChDohwLYFlivXypvSmer22lb2GuTVP9mYBomeKPZSWKkdhCnOSQ@8gopmv47UbKj4u@eBKPk80hH5N2w/IFvYJbqHb9b4Fh4Vagnu@6HimgeOZtppQNzUS61wJlBYFU/Lh8IyHmM6zth5XnvFlRYw@NL6tWx9cwO5iAUcLD@FRBtxrJOe13J3YtMplXrdBbHMXFKlqhXFBTtOlYTHPHUHc09RtOG0LDoeto4eHTx9/HRrdYrEo@W30bI4f1locaw3bcQ6ZFkeH7cGSbouWwos4cLIbh@Pp0vCNU1u8IUu4sAZlQIdUAvbz67jky7KIPL9WdyEeDxuhqA/rbF4N9AWphKqOjk226dN1DAQxxokt3QcSqLdA7xT11iS6cqLVwouiWy1qvlotXLzUavmtGBZNMCMu/Ty2kZ54Ll1Uye9LuRAEOg@APTxkLz7ZPWEnn@yzR8/3PmVfP3zOXuw@PcF93c@eP3h8sMfgt//0eJ8JC8sj8W4p7FACXR8aHQOvAMQj2XKMIO85oxmXO4k9ibsf60P2idMxcJpq29OH9wfcotjGuM5j7UN3dIZjmCbdHzY0x7jegi6/gm4sKjdd2m6Ha/kZhG1Dn3aIfd6h0zV7JoQVsO87Mg0v2PXFLBNKEORtsNk2xZUkvOeKlg7RjXS4AusCousQHuduAIzO11/RXdymxyMYXYX5hAufD6bgyf7Rk2OGJwfsHT59eHBycPj0mD06PALrs68fPP0Y6HlwfHJ08OA5elHAJ4cPDx4d7O2SA0cgozDcu/9q4o3XoqBgcKJK5wxnvunK9dC2OOqNGjy70GnjocfiExulj6lb5hujG68KEw/VF9zsSFMFLLG5e/TxZ9DmM@M1znAGU8G0/kB87tF9a5sZtk2pQWWpQ32r@tUVmj1ZlWg@YjhjeP2CUaVt@gkyp1gAnBbxdE2DiXu4RgXHvvlufqrLAWhIaANgI6hgwUqN0bUp8Xhqm0DWIbWO5eBxjDw1vojQt2DU@8FSk6pAFPPXyiBQ3K9wYON4kFoNHYDvwUHzkx27PADLhg48AMtxB1RFD3DtCMv7ISbjwwmKZ1bgDq@Go0c0LcyKocMDnXqxJR8nXm5UpDoLr53Csw0suhyHj/LQpX261zFNiuJReLw4xrJ4xTD4lWUgE/lUIq1tg5AiCJseTjX4y9743Z7oC9yA64T03thjiZqksBNcHGTYJr@WqG/pNl8CNV@6Q7zHSnh6Tc1fZmuG1/nQDpCRQwyIV4kt4hHGe@hrhcZd40HMBzdS1P01knSlXrAE7TYEHtxA4BcBA4DkhZ5Oh1oq2l@KYJyez8oJzwGOxHHbd9HwwM7dScdYiOCv2kq8Mt@8kXwipxb6ScE6RcIOiuiN4YJaSVOZPceFOk5ilS5AQSnYGTijscnLMLGYA5pxomYOQmPDBqm9rNUXUkM6XE/RduxIom3g4hWptoEp75IqcTyfOw/F1/w2TOB8aIT5ujtER2/jlePzubMUTiJdGDj8AoowzZXj4OdsTJhw/VOYy453DC/UK9XqDx@cyu9epvBWPS4W@EWWwaJD/AFjYlpQPWiejxYsuqh3@TUtuA3Jm7Qxtr8Gz5eWWMsDYNAPHJjQr7vfqoZ@fLnxTXfcI3PdnRzfvq3xWDJKJv9uU2@QmEu3FGsESaYoTpP5S0AishOQBVmfCFxSBDOU1/dxXwyWQhUoYqMcwX77tbuGfBES5K496YFk8a989Is7hC@xOq2omN@AiztbouWR/iLxoJasS@n5ghIWIWciENGpALIqSZFlKdRe3QD3cD04kN93B1daix1vHj4I2sO10D4INzm5GhZvliKw7g723RqwvHH7hcBC3lOrAfNG8ia0kNND5kxtxsLVtOtTfHmj7KjuARhse3EEJQQaSW1i0xR1cPhxgkeQomDmCtHxycP9/6e4p91qI1fyN/0Uok2CG9ptmwRCMCYxYBLP8pGLIRmOIZ7Gbjt9x9getwF7Evbc3R/7Arv/9xH2Ve473F/7FHfrQ1KrGwOZkz1nck5wd0sqlUolqVSqKh0fC5v3J1AW5j3cMrTlNIiw58WH2No27NNk52mhSW@WtfCkviQs2tS/xwbzTOI9MFVIGcSV9NCTRXzXcyec8KwnVxYSIcj6niZERbkkdl/VHBQ1JOA72AMCsnGnGQ20ZjYzw4tPGJlG4JJuLsvGpg0/WVjz2o0XKY6mJiDTJsjvomfJ7P77xPLxhqqHBSwMp4MNboMkDesN7BPqUPEQMnpesgcf6RbVpWhkzwJ2RtEODb8KSQn7xxmKGImFcJaFjWldCscSNZaPF5SYQwaJuAz4aOkpE9miGRLUFE9fNs0OdeJFL5tcgkDIxKv13ppcAcUv7kr6svdsvE6WtUBujrUFwqahsLxA7ayEXXo40zO0hV5LTw/pqmC2fbSq3P9PVbxKJGpSNJ/ZGJUIkNdWV188BTvdClU896OweQ1Jz5/jqyHs72OQ0TQi9T5wbu3QVekxAzxCOjatVwMmVRBEnRlrSqLttBiZ@AEurBcCZDDqON5WmK7VEZMUbrOh84pkQqcs99pgDGHdUB4196h/93h1OCE/Wd/8H6@PBxtmQtPBO7TKPxiMoiD2yjOiqBif0H81@S0YjfqUjf2ZrhBKltyYHnW2I287NnjlVmEinbeZLelI7yQ2u3WVroEqIfWihxeUonavlFbv5Yols6l7tf2qWKJogJ2ELtIe2Y4x98yH/ccQoDmY9BK4fJAP37NoA/4DDq4CCWQib74s0cZ5EjeiCEjNDboIRpqFyrm1mO79TtTy@xjSw7WfRcJ2n0NB0sJWj/acWZr1QilRHpCLhv0slHLtnGdTUfiGCl2ElATBvYnfjQULPTWUpeQj18r7@eJ6Ye21Ra3ru2P3qvH6wl1qlW0Bi6/fv4quR7ftX7uDLzcd0RPDv15OWtPffxNi9aV4AXWtPOdIsMW1cp7CaL6Cv@vidYE4VyL4hqLanttCeHyVnRCLIt6Hl@YFX@NGm@YN9JBIcalYulJciC524/JVY@2i3C8XSleN/kUJnfzGy@XxcnE5ix@ewyoKcwyfzDfGF7immlrXoH8j8IZTuolOuoYIcg2BLwf@KBzsVw7fJbRxKACgCkzaepNCnS8nnUNrNvQ98frBbVaqyVyBHGuhgGTNkVdQEX3aSZ@M6ph2CJhBr7ggzUYT@jt1rLmCdz0cDyhFBfpD1hLfwm/WnHJjKpBGAbI0QhUOkO5kjyZxniweDPHXKVtR54osrhXRd9IxQDSwJE2H9rlto08hIip9uRoXVuQFfusLIoG38X6jYmJzk@7mBVaLPNLioSmHPyKHicIFPuIBCPwM6bQBqyDJPSK3Dwuaj@9FfOAvpKMak58MGchbJCliCpp/i6/k30TlN4EATPg5lrk8qeKUkhcIkuw7SMoFDEKW3PjjMQO6VXKnzGFjETbXV46Bk6U40QirlWSC73O3SE6mFfyTLcgV6e1eM3R@h7MTSeicWr5FSEvqUkrawp9eXCxrFMupYiqzQYq5J6mBmi7YHh0EMKymYifo9QBppsVcTA58JP9eWf@yrj9qYJ0XGnlOz91LzyXSPU5npOJcHizwcaYNM5Od@RrnuxN2nM29V1dZkPDiQU@3PBBJ4rylx/JG3njQDOPMW7ormSt1wmYiIWekfJ7R@5wynyijGVynNzhd8veK7HmNZSLv22T9@GvJDgrIeFbamqS41OuHvTe8aOkUZDMbqCkEF8f@JrbjQSl9MOV0AhIc6vlp2G6VYyjLRTXj0Jixtzbf2p4UMt5k02iwF@O9gTVjjBhUojqXiXATcliEeih53gBBMJHRhBq5W6rwVBaeGmAx17yqlr0g7w1waFp6iJfRL/Ib/lGDPYmcypeZnTjHmE@48ezdnCQQTbrz9mwyJWcTdBfhj7JRj6wicd3TNMTZk8ShoQXWdQbsg91BNfi8nifMiULNFPforlMkpeMMRcW@D3UhJt5Z/8wvWe98kLGHvWAiKrjN8MkLy0o4uI@DaBxhbCeKRRNdD4c9PHUkge@WXKhloJCVVTxuiSEaK7tn1dCyh/O7@CQd0qGQJ44Q8i0aiMQJ0XW3i85k6AE7uMWpFTUu4dizKv0pKzRgzLxYYTfzQFxHfGoKu/2uiQT3HI8epHQ09FuBZ4GMFoH0Y3FTO6G8aJH06eg3gtHDYEnbsKy/XIetX3fe4Xnuq2LhRdEg2Y08Di54L17GDlZAJJWwUgAxdrX40rKMs@EWnw3nEKAr9nGh/wi8GdwE/X5gVWDFoIwRCK1RMLoJ2p5lHQf6EBjhIivjyST6YQ@uRy1W7oDQ5QMzopdw5PJxGHAY/uL6zMfFLTorcy08tIpPm6Grb8I2ElB5nHQGeDpMBxYYJoDpgYWugjEQZckRSZTo7FniQrLLFSqigBoY58Q4m9Bk6A/GYQt6hjRZVg9A8TFIXFm/ncIE6mv1fHQO9mYhgO4xMQUUAuoo6TEcLHlo/odwELJh6ozdVz2Th9lvQGMFhnswCmH2jQlMvULFDNyhg0/e1@qifrR38qlyXBXw/OH46GNtt7orts/ojBsPyimarXh/tA@ziz5N51PzI/hgV@pQ0qYEq3J4Jqo/fziu1uvi6FjUDj7s1wAagD@uHJ7UqnVX1A539k936fQdIIjDoxOxXzuonUC2kyOXalXFrLicONoTB9XjnffwWtmu7ddOzqjGvdrJIVaGp/oV8aFyfFLbOd2vHIsPp8cfjupVgQ2zdmv1nf1K7aC660H9UKeofqwenoj6@8r@fqqhR58Oq8eCjASMVm5XAcvKNmxhsSZq527tuLpzgg2Kn3aAeIDgvivqH6o7NXyo/lyF5lSOz1wJtF79yylkgkSxWzmovIPGWdknqAL9snN6XMX4R0iJ@ul2/aR2cnpSFe@OjnaJ1vXq8cfaTrVeEtb@UZ0IdlqvugIvq6OqAQZQC9Lhefu0XiO61Q5PYM04/YD2Dg508icgDGBZgaK7RGA0g8DWApGOjs8QKtKBOsAVn95X4fsx0pSoVUEqoEXFzomZDSoEIp6YzRSH1Xf7tXfVw50qJh8hmE@1etWBDqvVMUMNDTLOgHWg0lNqNfYT4MWPwKyW4lyXulPU9kRl92MNMZe5gQPqNcktRLad95LmHkbDNZQo4QB1Bv6VqVjp3P90E2Bwyfsamdk6Gh0xaedotworsgxWZccJp7DqrKdCKZlpsNLoRHhNhKxpB5fX3WbY7wzQx1QXY8XHVdR18doXB2@/OLceuV1D6leoQCbTbH6sNGGjW282Hfd7SibQeKqEVIM/lsuRbcQg/rjzRsXPxgbTfTNBqK3n8qCTDPXwAAJzMvWfs@mbfxU4Ip9vB7IYOu8jYKU6ivjY5AsepcDUSM6OeEVHXCVpJug9lOxABbMKvNdqop4ULSMp0yCCP/1v8QsvDsYHmJ1Z3ZXP4yaW0Ah/D1Q1XAmFRKA/MiJB2KEqvSgIfu1mC2Z1uOf3uoNBO@s4qgzlHcM@sJt1nih@GXRTxXPp8oQsHTvL6PmR2neTCKPPnyXJhOwXb0Qty@Kf5ph@HIUNx3xArSlVRcpqqbTMPufiaJHkChnaAt0rqJNR5juo/Fz7hLu5wsrLUur7e/2dxxbaC2IQWljwGlTugn7eX3AGGGAUiwNIEsoIGfm8UUbZm@jMt5DxC2a6Ddto@QNr9ZeA1nUgCQiy137PrBNX41E4MbGHefjdceVg@3RvD6ZOxPbl@uqrtZKlw2797PLvGdZDkWIp6tgQ1nGQ0yjJGCU7IPjQSDFiacfsTwycz2NGjKyuOo0@YpwHbbeRtGTCiQybG@F9NX000bMDpIMtKADHvKX4debIlAyQTTTVwdZc@RMS8X2QlYgHpDFLb0q9NsE/CFsPfzXEdYMkA0kWo9i5wLmwu6B5z95TpqK0uaHAPZjFsxUfcxg3TQNSdZH9LHrX0pvkbaMXIzZlxPFK3U4lAYn5NBZC2VX0eWR/oDgjUgFM0cPgy8@S3@DxTAa4o3B3fjSujOtAxj1dEvXUsTJaNrohIV9slaGLnj/XNW0K1PI7Eikae1KdrAODGKOBUMF7R9DGNwm4pOOIpKskC9i3i474ypyKwTsQTklyrHwHzp3VHAmlpOKHyHcVlUIwLB3khKl2q@uwVJYzHcdCkTNBph@iB8H/E2kyA/4m7DgBekwtIwjgd1GSoDKtYPtKRAlv1UGDcboRU9P8dBaDuTM75otumDy9mbB/DZBA9s5UfTijsIed7AwCIJOjYsMcv9ok7YsPW6e3tiOL4zlJv3U1zAq5Vqil4h7c3NqFS2KXq85W8MURDuuajAr3oah4yxu3Sxr1sGVKbeXFs8hmcI6K/5FfIgWIHvDEpV/YajXNWQU5ytQ8IEMtGQtOW0dMArH07sFTuyVhhMhMzP3y5EsRCkBvIT7320lXfgwEm@cmIy7SSixOKAoexgPHbTIuPjJk3SUZYvYChPOsTcoQvBVkfIsLRI@hU6i@GJrIPiNDEawktjqM4wzidOt4QFpaVm819qSZRA7V2J/2ORB9wFotlcPjAB8SQ9Nd3hMH/hRQ7n1fs5nF8kv1gYu2i1gZqyVkebwBpTUYjEB09LHdgKMbTh1PfJJKh6AfXY9k/EJYz8KR1EgooR@qQbGJd@@0zHAMeEItCsfordD2iD@oSVcBWohyeJJJbk1kgXkVj24ppWM4WS6K7Gacsgk0obCkRMRNsSa@feNcTFAZMjQgCoaR3lyQzSbVg@cOevjdDka/4tqPIlC/HbR1ZFIDJOkCuZNqfYrx2Bpz04eDiDQa0BWoAdGUKLIiTRuqwhr9SrKTtGuy4@iYGLuUWvLH69FMqqyloKKYcWXtwHxrOehMpNKKDA2qg4UWV1YJlVkbrrsHN2MULTR5bC3s876eUjZYiCg/U6IjPvG8qZ/O8Ekq@cvPIhw98AXPuKUIigijzIrnqvfnOcIPbQo@hcGobepEQZJp@0NUv9HWZ9AnXlSqQxn2r@WPo2AKO4BWPpzkCUYz@9PgS7@5M@j53XAQ@rBPwzDuE57x8HFKj9hh3dHgNqLLfSihbWRqT@Nnji/DYdjwXZ9LlozQXNE4GGZNM4XxaFr5wmEiSHOORoDxvZPE38N0jDRd5uVqXMhK@p@SPV7RKT1Y9kVxVmE@0UcAcoLbSllQsA/pmByTDOfT0r0Ml49lMHC8FDnhOw9Y7CUwfg0komOYBMYKmXtmCWYjcGf2IMaN9sRtUwzCEQZaCnYDvHImytJn18cbfmEWeYOWAhuiuF4wivIpygTjEOLD9GFyr7z6k7EHBH4A/eKLWdwyixFoiuuoaEsR71dklFHAhcwDQ5qjaSaGWSzswirUSwBtTtJQk8nTh6hBlj8gFMkwe/e4EkdkFjY@eF9ctglTTnPq4KKyKBYdituBIkhlnC08zLDBU/azNPjxEJc1Zzgx7UjIWQPph0jVAirhZaYp81oTZY6p/PSIWVn53l5LEbA8y@TMuLQ3ayvJhTxQQl5f8VhrMILJ2E5RT5p6LEbjwXDxO6n34NwxMzLbLFq3HOdJQ2BmtjIslkttIm15io/TkpXGJ8U0SYqRpRnwEG5f6VmzeZqIk3ITx1u5OX2CDg/RLLab0ouK7u82j31cFG/QolctNHpIEe4YpLSkvzea0PDmwzOIhMnbqybNGE2cMppTfjRApcikqfT9FCLuk7in6NEGymG9baCd2T8PEjVtJKdCnqqkRJBLpCcGbkenTZiXhh00vsAwcSzh6klKC5wTd0pHecXcJQYZxgQGiFJxkIv1UKzBjTsrxUd0O0An20RroSLORPC0ZVo46KD/mmAUlV8qd6TFQ3OaK16UGNJEQ4JdBeV6DJLyN4fXRnNCUO6RAob4DFLoFt2bm758f6t@tC2QDyBwaUqWlr4FFxvjiGXABv6YSc0JysBxVbJkYkQlB0KTpgYYC7BL6fYC3q6i9BeOmOPRukEOI9hA8Ocs/izLEhjOe62gqY1FJu0pZnEkuXm0OSK3xUVihuJ3JL8ciizq0sYVAASMMZQvFwEChjUl7PFQgELvmJyXQFT2ERQsF3FYwkeKihrbec5IR6LKDC9XjRyFWTlemzByM4GAYDE7T4wIyCyzs8RQYKGbiYuR49Xs9sQ5QCBWvM8Uh66QvZKkoe45JiDdY1xw4hmlURRuQXIwJb5cdRKJmr8p9XXBSC2kU4E@GsNGrphOXS8kUhPVrqwkiyZKAj0cs9ZEIpDCMRHWs8KP/SPXFDPkubYJNTYZCSlD2mfjPdOwy4R9m/fXSGySU7aSMRQ80zNcbb@afMVKIij74wHYxSIdGWDs9h9urbJMVZjIuwIoLp1ydsnyhpAkVhuXemwW7nRVpD0doEDtaQcd8fFkby8R9vVyqgyNroLRaqFQQCa@NIPfK9tqVCWFg3wyd75z3evlh7c/jT5e5mnuDwK6EmBD7aAD6BIYFJE3GHX5ZgjEAbJi7px0ZMW9/nWnY17BgCeU2HnQbZxTRkMQtACF2ujl4wkpgAikXGB/wQZi@34RevTd@ixoSijqGApKo0nwja1Oz4A8@KGD9tn6pIqA4cSsrJlg3XLKW19xBcGbTaizKHyx8zU2T7bfB73ewBWf8HpgjBQwd5cusLdnFihwFjxhJO/e64ji0boiuAl7hl8xZjF5HcGphUndM6HiwmNs/OOgW50Ms3bjsw3LCjR5GZu5jPGpXWF3bUcGi/8OsMyHgPZ35b7yh9kW0SmdGZZ6OYLjJ8DoRdGdufdJZHFIJyZp9nRuJOpsdD0K1gBNd0gWULHsqXupJQ9k18S1zyfFDtKwwDAkThhz5ftKoKvZnzct3ow7ne@bFekaAO7YPzQj8k0oPzYh0hkAjUA5/ICeGEX7X3IwrPdSAUVYwMHLOu7PO1igiQUs61mr/NtttlKpiIXh8rKoVLbhIZcTle2K2MUP29tiF9638f15eWV1tcRz7q7zFT5uq493YhtgkIZzufVltAuvkFZGvzG01sYuXsiXF9zSQrO8uVWK8o3KNrr1w9M//u0//vHv/5mvyJf/xpdteml81pk8z8svtL4uPL8r4Xtj92Jx4bKxMLxY7JaQy/5JUcMHtXHOj81HvdGlleFVwPhKdqRqn03RZ2RRoW71u/JHv8LssiEyrSifkV8jvjmK5thMKzC@B@hHeQlbeHXpQHorD0hkAOgU1fHQO60ADfBgvQFKAi5oB8rl@WxFKe4xHIzOoE9VMjISD8msNwH6tMSRFNAXF1asXNiPgj5qwG9I5uXmWZYPv@G4Kfk3//kg6m4PJmLpPCuWCmLJFUu2TT/Ftdfw1VnIh@idy9lgO2DbLqTERwtoZiiikAQ92j/QXTspclvWAl3Zg5BUmArKzF5wrt79kbMMX7gWda05vDRTsIqEDpmwSObrQv8OuuUr5LizE642JCg05S6GKjNOVHT/ogjkR2wIENd8xQTZGECVeNJHHsn4lFdfZF9bdJsQAUayHr/bo3GPH2AtWuhLm@fEXgqvOSLzef6Ka2OJnaEJbUzh@mME6ECFt5MF8iRczCxabOVttJKayV7YZvsk87GtwzQYK9t0LvSvwmACtuY2CbfQl34t0pCbj1eEHerjFaMqO237LSyjyNV1bxwOpbsC1Y4D6quu7Y5HEvYoAWI4HLN/4/4II0WBihSV6ha@LGsq2gNsOo@EvnRNhw52PD45MoiQ/5yFsf0tNbadPHmJKHZgHiCktClfxw97kYy6MiJid/3RJd4O6HfoQrUxn5uRPg@vSU1hPOhopD2CTCbn8XiGpmSGI7975bsiczg4GfnTGixbIPmMW54DLcQQTIgEDj5Z9azmKYS5RbJLiCK6KWQ5hJcX9KbyejTuW1v7nGCXqqEgw67gIEiwE1Ey@JboqxQdY67@A51gonxv8tankXKKpZkXLY0kJNt0m6Fhdm/oWKoGc@zogWNbjKoemYoXZKFrXGiv6OAXZvIexgiQddvSC1C6Iqy9xvpxdeoGfT@xOA17lnL0z5cEr4s4nukqSrZGstTNp8X4xjvECuTIz8koELw2qXBG1lw2O3ceyevcMuY6QkG@tS1@3hehvoCOLjAjzxBx2g95skytUPEdGJ6okeU/QOj0/C7gN731p8iK55nsm/m80/h83r9Yyp73v53/7hAmckpWq2xOZORhtpqx5FiBlTHvJl6VVVqkQg2e95MZzvuCfVgMEgAi@Wzjc/7iWx4QOs/gnfLnGSZIossQk/zj9eURfP4empkkFvmMNecsOarzs2@KjoC1lX6xD/mDw7@AhdpUkpoe9jmjDoAiP93frtnlJMqvrxRerhRfwk6oG0xyo@Aa19tcdH0ZTECUiHA7C0vP@e8JbkgQ4m4S@SX4OIF28rUm7HsSSSclOYXKYU71WJqtoIzHPAH5gcoULhVdXBydx8fDR9zwuwJYTuWlWFBsOmhwXxbXz2hwhfX4Ec5rae8Q5ki0MmAbEVKh5hCyunzlIQ511HBZJD8nT@xg7FYCAt2bzxirRX/Qz0lhzfEWSyhEo9dMb72wXkiP0XtDNDFCF6QwtTgviltvXv39v45@y4wzWyv5TyP4HWd@y6ytZ/gRHuDthXq7yWxlNjHb2l1mmoc9MDy@@vv/QPmtnwAOpkw34c/WqoK1Ns1s5cpU5Ftmaw0eiisrUO///u1v0IYF3rHhXawLTVcQYiVFkR2/T7wL6aKGreRt6WI8rZBjFsJgC0PYm8MLGkZNVtYLpKbLSKuKm0BGvlL2KHKJJ8OsMZkKsSZD2VOAZMQFylhBjkEqE4qOMGw3lNkGMm@MpvjlmbcWwQ7gF2nOoavUphvPIjQZWuBtEXRglmuE/Tw/bBXe2Nq8Y8NWNiUlJULi1k7OtesvSv8H)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/tzsi6)

```css
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\          /* IE11 */
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}    /* IE9 */
:before{content:"314"}}                   /* IE8 */
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}      /* Navigator 9 */
```

`X-UA-Compatible IE=99` turns out to enable not a standards mode, but some kind of semistandards mode ([link](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8)).
In this mode IE11 understands hashless colors, but IE8/9 don't. Navigator 9 also recognizes hashless colors.

`:root` is recognized by IE9/11 and Navigator 9, but not IE8 ([link](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt)). `:root` is used to separate IE9 from IE8.
The `prop: value\ ;` hack works only in IE8/9, but not for `content`. Note the space after `\`.
So `color:#fff\`  hides text in IE8/9, `color:fff` hides text in IE11/Navigator 9.

IE11 `}` is on a separate line for Flaks.

Comment: You're actually a legend for continuing to go at this for all these years. The link to this at [Polyglot \(computing\) at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_\(computing\)) has to be continuously updated every time you post because of how long this chain is and how much you've contributed to this xD. Seriously, you are incredible.

Comment: @LittleWhole thank you

Answer (score 4):

## 318. [05AB1E](https://esolangs.org/wiki/05AB1E), 14570 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26 ^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_#          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v                    @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM              @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99>ss<!--
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
X#  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa






















































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::gek:>Ex Cr Uithar5"3.c"F ._#a gi[s]pogr34*61  prstd6,1 8,8R ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on; $/op>s'0}e}equ7+?4[0]tfc;[ ]5:ore在ｕ    
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\              \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@PadSD4s5H5I65AvSYhEiABfpMi1Wq1@j35dbfakvr1syk@NkiCJFogwAZIiWy1umzPrjeeZGczHiflODN5jmcz62ymarJTOxtnJ5mpSvbHqdT8lD@g87G1ldqK/wPvOecCICiRlNqZVG1tLSQC9/Pcc88999xzv9u6N/j5z2P4sGeONetbzpiNDW/Muq55brgKezBj93XTy2tZQcBQu25/MjTssVcRYkxlzBvr7phZut2f6H2DxcBVY3N7z7TGhptinmGwtmE5F@CfZcw2LtiB3TG7AImNnTPDNt8YLvjlGHtoWG@Hb8es4wyHut312Mg17TH55hl7poOlN@mcMb3tjV29MzYdG7wKjD23LX3Y7uqMgo9cg0cqMgDVOaM4iz4lxp44rmdACk7H8DwHHcvgqLum83j36cfXwqsZ9rEOSI0sY3oteVVlL0zD7V6PobHPTh49uu6aZZ/Kjs0e3URJzbHdydg5GF@Hn2e7fcPWmaaUFe26ZwGIOTasUqaUWfACv0emC6Wp@6VWmZeMPRm2DReI7xfhhTkeKBDhxOEEZ45tzZgxBWCAYw@CGWNmYmmxfCaDIeH/2Og4dncOHpwMgANwjeFoPGMysx2fB8DLcZk30juG3DUsc2iOjS6zTMDO6fnYeAwKnJ0ZswvHhYKXOSsSIt7I6Jg9E6P4OfAEZLaHRnvSZ85kPJoAeh7rmp7etiBYe8a6Rk@fWOMUa4MfEI/cLwaG7aNk2n3Mx4u5C0KwoQpw7DdVoI1pWQzQOUN0MGmPbaPHBbpj0LZBWBpdBLU/JxdA0i0vyP1iwgvJYLxnrtN39SEwatcgGnx28Ix5HccFG/wwLK8F68B09DHb3mbx/acP46weklFx20JI0hq7ZIzFAk92rlsTw2NDfQZp22OoXMyh8gtiCBCcxTfiFRbPZpmWYbkcy0FlKzEtn2FQJcpggFqrZVX4FZhWYjkV@D4fT2E6PVfvm5bBofQdq4eAisixWp5p8M7kWFYtxVM8RIfSKbJsiRWKrJhnRXiXWVmDhBBqjqnlPPwK8AMoZcBChV82x1MLWQNZCrLB9lhPH5rWjEMfjRB8h@VVVgSIgKoKkLUSQChrCGHxicIbD4C4A/0cQMqWeYYiwwilBpZYGj7pra00iS2UjzxJb2BYFqYKxAIy5UusCKkWIOM5SBloqZW0IPP9AWWf8Cpm4Ac4FiHHJSBxBqiVQXIV4Qd2EEUayBwNBIwGMkNTwV0DcxahQrgC@BWgvAq5ALrWJdqChIW4KhIThYqKNIBoUAgsC0VRYDko4iwWcT7LAE9AoFhgIFdKKivlWKnIgFzlDAPSq4AMlr8K8kwFJFQEBsWqQrmqgIgKDKMCUDWbZ0KErmoW/SFuFuICCdQcxMmBGcpFLeAP4kHBq5CkCmlqWnnOXoCblodM5rPEd1oBCq8IfkAsDXDVgFs0wFYrgT/GLQHhSsiWxYAQujUa6EgLKAFkZmA1IEgecCLYEB7MWjHLWYpCt42x2RGuBKhZvBWMSp1AgqAUAInCdIaNKDDgnHsSoRSUQCgtCqyJZ1jARSBHOjqYkW2hxqP0COCYYwVlLTRVhnOOjSmJgIVkPBITbRdbUpBZXcN1GYaFBtdLkUDxJm3PeD3B9naOVw8klAHCtaebVogAVR19TG0BfOMepDdbRLvnOkOqX0MUGJbjjFaIXhBPFwjoE@fCmKM@l176aGSBTAd3Awgx0S1A5kInnYBUhmiqHCGIhPE6AxMAUlIgW03X6BDt/axD7CxI4UUUK0yr38silAeRpiHLRg4IVg/j2BPLqkCTZ3RYtp7uGudpdOHNx2KzgTgEDQq0iT6Itg7tOTWoiEUI6Z6mUFN1EpSs5wwXs8bFy0GY9YGJzYB1oc@g9HogWYypPgStg2HTbkPjPQSO4SWIJeHxxueAdR07Pg6hXLjQxEKmw5wASItoMjaHBuhkDkTBEs8R0ijcCLP2DFiZqJVTSCXjmFwjlCJcJxR3yEUceGWBxq076SDVMG3TJg6CRsGjFqsOcLniqaABqpxr6F0eDDUMxCiiI0GLZwDRfXWgQ4BQSzFsDzQeT2EmqobA8H2nBzxGzTSoGxB1nk6H8o45D52mSkcRiNLIN8Mzi5msMxoxcAcdBdB6lClBO@u8Mtkb8LQGHrM6E9edsekICsAcQqhxx@n1gGnfGKMBgGDDLuvMOlArIZfINELXIQnUGV3LcmjbNCCMbUC29559nfUNoDa0yj3AlDh9noHRiLJApNBt3mLbOlAKs9AZzYgsACaM0XMcBd27juERj4BGE9Z4TMwz@lQjoHr15jJoiBoIMCdoBTawLAgcv1YhfExQWJoZTMov/I8NG2pMB5gR6joUH@qku6wH@n@ksUYFT@90jNHYZw@HpJhpR5Saw0eo1JCr7ANTvIGweR/0sQUMBAgqBJwTacH1MxKuqOyTrqWjiPU7GdCm20aoxjIuUKzZjeQhxPm11MWXGGYBg5fiChxGVBNQwyPZMBmjBEGhaHYGKALHKGRIy4BK5k5uZh/cosm7Qyb3wrQRGxWkjaCkQyfEYzUMGX7WTUDKyEJY9QUHDLrgcAto3RsugeyESFrdqKuS1hWQhbcBHTq2swQqEDOEi0EWfagsiBmPUWroVsiMVF28hTJCOT3v/2L7BU3naOS4UDO40JmhJONFFuEuh/dVEmETIUHfebFFhZYiju38eMz7XSML@kJUxbCmgj6pg6QAIcZ7ASDzHJ5iBGGq9QTLx@@CJD5nJmhCbdtAlVR3ZxwIZA9aZUhoxkzXBTF4jm0Db3qCNkQhPoWmQO92UbIiOajeX09cQY7em7TN6fWuRgcdlVeecK67rIe9DBd0DahEiXjPi0tVcqeYES8x7YzGaYrK3yIEpEAKFHmiBx0XaAgegaA5ntmdhLhQxcQUEyfjXkmUwIARuWrGvqqPxtexewVuyDTDM6jXZKuyPrTasgxvGd0IE/RIK@ihu6BeQCUELbtc7rZ19hakh8vk6R7FRrWQvqqSC9My7G6Ylk8IxCWaX4Un4bkdMsiRVg1zgMEp59RILBDwjpSgiCI4pNN@@4kOpORxP1JnuOPEpiECluAaiMQuQxUdGoAEIWOCzmF2zHHL11Lu3Qv0lY1aDZgNlCgQm10pqtwHYykKSGoIrJAS4ieijJ3jMdaNhAT5xcBXHBvQloBTa3V2OR64UOPIfiVAICCrYCMnB4T1y/mpeTbpXi9oGx0xkIi1DnQlszMWqwI0/rw21NZRNb5AVVD@40hVZF6MT6BvMC@5YoGKfjDX8FDrrfmoREo4gRj4vLqURDyq7zZn6L1Zx/JVAm6Cys6lURvQP/N766EgSvk6QVBpb9RUDgSrA4fDnu2efFLz6yL3TLdNu7LgYDkd3SLnTQwuBnEfHzw42j36emsJDMtsV647pM1cqYBN7WQq9@1JOqdolc0ojDngh631sDHiYhhR8L2Z7EwjqtKsA43LNCDn4dGn10kCmhCSg1IAM/6uqTQ8DChdQlv3BtcaYdZPJiHJMEoQlskHLIAZGhB19NcDfJ5N3rzBwruO1Mh3R8ysic4BBI7pAzuIp6DnNQUs8Gr3eItIcUELNW0cA52boiEDfD5Grfk6MqRKR1jm48NH@0c1AjvQvTPDsmQKkvbGoEvpblcBnrcmXUNYFgbEH5g6LKnMEUd9mnBdSuBOZ4HA87JlK@ADAOziKA6TrWGQNW8AuO9dzxu5yp2QA8hOEK7rlVF9qPOhiEbwwCaugz3dZa0oecwbq9BpaYsV@i42W5183ijmytFmqzNPsxsFOiSl2HQCvdEFrzNPRhdlrkX6arWP/vHjG4h7pERCV0AOMPMsplBaniVg70U2WdxL70EPzbEM5QVJPJGJUjodDwY/lY5Hfc5I@P2pOU5kJP5VJQgLqe/uHmgPg8D@QB0NYFCnAbvg2DK5PZxs6HjAI7ZjOX2HbUEcrh0GCYLatDKbu33HvlFCOjpiVmM4ewHyF8dr9BG0NeYb6jhSrGh3lc986LZ3AVJaLWSRSEQhApWm8Mor/VwHcs3zfXzwjX1oRNR8JhOaM/QACSJxiFxo6kRcyYHJkJDi47M0g@FMxo3aHnjIkakEzLQv6MKIu3PvpY4kMZX00vBLUfqqc4Pir5zZNdYCF85aYIiQ7ODps8cHT/ef7H5@Otby@QV7LlMuAOEgvTboQsqA0w1r6xavmpgtBBeDuuFi9QIpMIEOSjAkPvFcENwKBlE4Aiu4hs8BJb7qDOy4J13PzAX6yq/sDmehJ1j5eFA/InS0uxZ2Rlw@dYbtOfLPYDweeZV0Gmr5YNJWoNOaftVxLL2fpnjQMFhWWsWuy8Ehjmt4y2IAMt7M4DH4mBaoDjMaONStoQOdF5qOQ9HAEhw8DVZZZn8AfWGcszNcSQk5mHKT7kIPAfrK6TBvJIDJBrT1v0E5iZy1v6JqJc7XakbLpcUg2EL1h7AbPQO6TglorYAU0jUrO713eo/NQEojpOtAYkzZ8qdtsC2wGCiSNFiK/fyAOCQtcJgUZQXR6PUEB3FBSqXzmVxRLeTT0C2DbhrorDIOtclDfdwZyGNHBniy06NxgwgX9ryObveULd8QIAt630eQ1Wzji9NTuwkK@uk9wg0nwxqzZkNtSlV2M8qWH16qAvcuZA95N3AA3iUjsCZ92Qp51tVvirOuTrWry9Lj4chvc@QRe7ILitQbB@R114jWPYyQjnqmtxbCpjHwu/SSASELowr4QkqloUJBSwusl0a8ZFB6UT0EzgG5FYnA5qMZPB98CjoiR7DTjXxvOnGPxupRr8FBUm8ERKQx5g5KaQ/HB8fQOoacj1IaCheFNLsw4jh8rnt8kBIi@ROPQXzoq4UQaDA@HIi2wwlXYAKKRd1zkBzAVzhaOpiPMmKnHzgNEiSccPABNAibJg36IGcgMs/ILs8IT4lcFrN0ZjsXNkJrG6wkt80xH@N3Ji5O6JndaN4geFbjYQAaZS4i12nmr210@Cgrj0y5gE6gzobG0MGhBNCuSBQYlAWdzxpiX9DDgWqoVhkZJ04Avszu74EU6xh8vEgeYicKWGqfxcduelf@RlqX3wA3r9GtMPO70UlsKvSTgAA0EhnOYtMoiT8CStqJM6RAL2i8BT0fBOquMJqNB5Bj4DBRrzkjw77e5@M9woRUpbnWeBwEvmknLuMbGxvxSrweT4FpB0zbaNpBUxJMO2SSyYThFDRRjBSZ0LdBMdCtGb9qBJCnUhN5YIqawxtzlNAblUq2mdIbqv/V8CtBUQDlIbSMH4ATl2o1NEqSWL/AqRrQ3yN530PeOe645sgnwVdBIeB2nwZZIgJ071Gbd40q9k3XU2RYc6HTaKCKmXDjp43MafP08rSbPL2KpzC2VNVr0D8E4TVODJW@60xGoLg1chUZZJvUyFaa1XYtnolvJRIl2YKEdEn6qCQldU7rRNwAnkqcnsaBpD51Gp2BS/CmKU2SQkIBHj0TehmWlYgrlyVIvy01pWQc4krxFIjlWjwOdOkgETzKNI4IcCZ6ZE6BlFAxoYmLzimQgKQ5Kayu3zBGg5kbDRCOuoGWjSPo8wl5qAwkxaNS8g2PH1XoFnr6gd7Lw4Fyi4N3qC@NZly6CxzT0/TC4pCg3T2Xe0NnrKc/U6DTpESay/hGPC3L0BKSD4dE2X5ieliFddtwJl50pHHpACimDq4ngwkIy2DlTAq4yhwJRmfgsPjmfYDOwmkebEpwxkrm814BgG5HgR8KUdRKcLIEtAtaUmKCXMTlJnxURiUkuOgJxubzhdFrJUytSnFYBhMy@7bjGjKQBGIItACElgsJdeavKjmgka8b8xK@LzVp2PE2DZCIjyxHJ9pycR2ZDxoNI/Ghfw5RjoyuYIH86IF4VHhZuEY3vSXQ5KzjDqCFgNygJNbC0hr6HmnHG3WV8RSiCglscKOevHcHSucF62qaVujke5XAD7kCiD2AQsJeqQ1d3MBLVsFT8gt5nw8LBX30p4cP9/nYCTW22LziOFpr6HQnoFf6/aYjw@6n2D7wk2k7QxPIEMR/c2YdOc6Y9/LBsmpkhneazeHE0mnM5/qwzNp4HaftWDQUtC7qPPzE9XRL54NQge/uZ09A139@clxTKpFAaf18uDZtHIdcniyn50F0zpGmWYPpIY8zpriZF7HdChakoZjxPQroMfGXo0EZBe5FdA@qFM6h@O4ldB/iUjTQlf1RBLKGjn7AMgXE5Wm4qsd3vFQzV@i@sg8WhlMpHFcc59heqhq5n497vQXnLDmfySiarLlzjpz5MrWFPmIUpTwPhGvWFsJEARUoTLh07Xo4X3iFSwwGhhXMIB6BYoKzZNC2W6g@Qd8ENXG@fswARXqEkyEkoXGKjXVA1/RuDFtAnRrJPLQQ26B6Am1YGjUXYTPN/CHuKtUU2/GnJj0uPR3o2tPoyXadT1hj18nlvbY0H3zfbAGI7Xo1WE20KhimFI@HwQgq4QYxKJs0bX8jq@EiDI/G1AWKUhW8NPQaplpGPp0W95tpj4jQY@Lp6fSjjPY5dD5w3dfmvXTfqGJyK6lFdj4O3RmA2GDJ6SLJoBwmds@xujKf9ILyZ7y7hAXhLzUIV56RwAcX0w0WnZm4iMVfHAjiMrJe7Qbca0VXvxkgssItBAS14ZK9PUudv2UNaMHOFW9kmeMmu1LGTmuAmR9PXPv6WjiuUrquPvMEf6VKje0effxZI9PkEIShjhNZJV5a02ApJejBoPfgilUw4XqbsTmmhp0WFpiYX1UBpKY05wHoAwyeQJWFCfk5QtTfGm/neekZ0PFMGIi5NxummCFdKT1LH48Nm/MWn01cTW4@7eMnU6Pkd/w5hArL0EQLKJom@gGKVXZ88nD/6EgBDvUS8X2ckKlAtdM7A9A3VmU6oGQ08xX2UTfOPsI4EvbCBahS0Jlo@fGBeavA3NCdgNRRFPQNNwGOEs6ldMCZpq8oIle4fALhqqnOmGgUAksYEuSJgFWW4v/c5j0nH88Ki7MkURLInbhXAdqakjKxzdeKB@0GqaEQJM77nrRMtraZIPG1qUrEP645xLlg6DKRFgh5aDTYBkg3Ci2y2jv2RSMjl5vJTdZsVvkMP0REnZ6W3fpLOHWfnnw6jASkj/OB3yvrXVvIG6RAI7cYi@OnAs8KPt8Csu6kPbtZS8VNTZRCZOU34MA9xetILlloylEMljaRCKGVUIsrmhbXS0Wy9Zw62dcWiEN2AgTC/OA0ZILnkm3UmCpJAWYc0Avdxa5zhT1zPM9sW7SCtWeZfCVY2FhXfML4kALKRJOrYsUgumF9hnqGhTFftswXA/uUIH9qaKAnhTkjh4TELpGYREoNqcjevkUHkW1qjNhAxFXDnL5XQZ8W5ONjB5B97K@CjuocJDT85SkoOk4FMei8Lc7/og/vGKTPr@m88rkYjcd1TtM@c2gWKTS1MoqaRz0zjD08s27G7JnegF4LQUMceFhtFXbesN2j15IANJniT9OTAw3T@xo2FKeePqIPjdgvSXlxacpCsm2jN7H7NKeJZia/viWkXC5R4F67ba4KCkTA1WbBd0kwkJVY8zQlp6hB7cEBHmgWQX7yPtE869dXNbEFukMjNYZY/vc/f7ML9L9ZOgNor3A8MzS0QFPAkpJ7KwvLj4oWei0vWD7sPrFMnQhDpttAdnQXsqRboWE5aJral2XQN4Y4UeGXOPAmvkAXXcNmHHM@zxh8lyeybKrOBrndWRX22iovnhRNKkF3sUtE4DqXaVAkErK8EIwpn9iJdNxR4N6OVLAUixEz83IfTMYT/gZ1@NZCNEf4W1c3/ZCZvN5WDeiQ6m3TWFPkrn426Try6KwfqsWFJWHnuaeZZRm0En@SuYXG5dnnGXTNPjT3wXdVsHn7mr6gz21c4dkTbyS3qW/f5TaqCMM1KbgWf68KYvq7lULDaqqZFr3uyIk@dGAUf41FGlewyhGimdfIbOntGapCgw/nsnC9AkicWieZzGRXTFiPRqvjY/@U4pfLy2NPlQ6nx7KRhzRfJSvzsTnKsL9u9pZShebKHOqWrHUjxpXCfNlyhxtBw5lSimOc4zzR@dKSm1MfG6TOxNLduWkNi8/xCCYnVo1z@82GX5c7jmV6WKGtVVIzWHM3TwvXKdMrsq7CXEbJLnREsR2XQ9NyKeB0xrgWdQVb3UGm8TWguNI2wieKs4pYHecCfys1iAF0hvl7eaP2ZilWd5BPstWxdGjKV7YIC6OOOKp5C69emJ5Br@WEPVuK6LhjLXVfrAXBeGJ0fPA2zvZMy/HYMb3XEajvAhX4ezlPR2lp6rZMo@xR8xoxFCyemBeobvUdq1Dqp3V4rSz1idtD0e9/7yrkQiGlqrcIqUADcmzV/64U7Wdp9@y2AqL9Xy4unI0Y17SyyySVP6mzOnfQN8AZweU5e5QpUUwlzccQVySMczkX@iz4/gKtxyrSBq3HaEYaNSh4GKFcAsPY5Vr2L5Jabn1q3bsJpRtgi7dlIlK4Z5YB7RW9bxQp0zLqB8ZQM5m7i6ieNTEmxtK@xmH7lYFbidf0M@6OVMbPxqY/BYCzDrjnJQz1xu8c3glrbKrRtlaY6NBrN27XZhaF2ggU8BH2np@B4Rkabsbo25PRQqkudNDso/UkG4yCKu10F7BDnw@VQ6VblKUFFd0z6Le208Q7ebjyrJbLZDK@DhOZylmwrOtMZcO4r0z@XkiYXOYpz8Pi9J0bMS5Pg8gSXdu4UgRpq/r2FLhcTtumbYxn@L6jNG07jvUhJQVCtWuiNgbKJa3hXVdiN9Qdf3cKm49eeDjm0e6tGrfgrY3fvQT6YL95XaFH55ruVJoyzqYOcaZr0bp@BCcyc3VbKrilG4eF@Kpea7Uu6Q@IqEpJKa6tdVxDddqGpfPPtJBbB6@sZNfCWxQa/iwwzhrzueL5HH/smlAazYBYZhc6KgNjaJB1jaKvd19NvOCzMtDUwd8q76lhdNLTfaOzKsDIBLlg43thcjqiLI0dG7pYY1xAiF0VC5eo@q6rJHAwnbiUyAdDvW/wcyrWScr5mAUu0@E9u7lx@ehFhS/N6UC0@QjzapaASnVmzLzguxTgk1kHynUyvH3E7Vrl7@Aw6B1q@6q1sTebWHvgDOyBMeAL0kPbqsoB/Djm54qsQx2w7g9wjdxotLB2PkpPy7Gsu9ATRSMXlI7TW4rTPu6qxS1hHwR3prfBw//cOn6nj7nsQMPKWjMwJtAuec7YGRky2VYFtXCsh79XydBg9vsXHURa29UHigTfXxT@rX3Lvu6MRyP6tEbWxKMXRZVpM/RtelOPr3mh1ZaO21feOMO24jsq/oIYmnRfLmLa5rgzwE3onLONvtPuDMzbkG4b@tg2z9LBqA@33qnvipQxmfwQnRXLBPK6MwX5pRb1P8bPwapC9weQeLMWGtboK8sG6Wi/tzzSzzoeHxBFE6vgmHCkNvJd4RXaTl95PTHHc6CRRVLhCC@fmUDDKtz9ZRkrNSvafDEXw/5yjZVcSko6KuSykQGFR105vrSwgC5SxbJZ/lqFUDSXhFFkwcuHkNtfVEQDhGZk6BbcF/hrYTXU0kbOHkz63k2ByUfsu6Ci4Wv1sAUtko6MWkObpdv@ZxWZNSuNuyfh2wKda2KsnVbJr51XoXCqJeuOCZ8WfKDoJivH0Cxz5PE3k3srZ@P8RVLQF78@ZchpM1vemfYLpmv0@CwImm5TEYcOzdOCDiJ3cE4fB9FRmHPFiwsu2@mDUJctNg8chF2ltixdf7S8@MM2U/78qdHXcRH3Y3OMq0CXcAWx7LJ1S7fC/tpE98yvTSBnq5gNj4LgM5Fu9MwAtC2B90Tvm51PFgoiRNInsL@ElH8W2B@dbpbFxcD0cA1VaFgzMIUsx5kYua4F/YYlIa8P3YenYMwrEN9fuTT0suF1ZzTDbWgzMq0bWTfHNMrqf1d1HVetLluLxMVkOJp4/mc5DrRKKzoKPTwjd@/CBODyaxCtbKBb4@Uj1ZEhV9DC/EZxblyljX/DtJw@@0Ypw0BpAyUMlfMljPMAmudnuDTItZdwIqV9x5lPHOiQXZ6x11C2RpbJpm2O14/mjMe4TCj4YmZ4y4FbH9KP8a3c/1AI8slyijy@Xdef73m@pX0Hzjt2Jm7HQGN4kEm0W@CnauwFy5pxq4iDB7FcRHtpa2dvoDl07MlYdif22lahsLZVqLBpqRBhA5b42v6T51KUG2gZ@G1aqAGdv4lnzeamlWsGrjGZaYMitlqOLoYO@hIP@blLR7QG@ZY4u3g4VIfE9UNnWX/n2cw1xnfuMIHwnwwfGh2cObw17afOE8d2oDUagaAcHhn8MIGFtR7LI2K0x7hdHujTvTWZYwK7ohHi2oY@MtpQvtbcdJe2iAN@qI/1FU0RjQ1S/y803corptU23Fc06Bcxr@rSLiL0iTGlvsVqhuF1UB53OlwlxvG4hTqyMGPjjRzH5m@Sthn4qE/WSxVoCuh197lyBVf4L4wLLO2fLWb18JwvFDG6/LSLVXl1jbZj8feaZUm2yZcF6K5peOnHeHgCuRVyTAbty1srQ4prZci8awSa7Lnu0Tz98q7GHKQ6/YBVQAPd7Tg4E@Yb1izQiZx4cIuYDjcN8LUDbSD8FCSW3pn4Zy/ehpY1bA/ptbLDECnNI6ON243adEzIWJ/eLEw@MuSfkRBZ1BWeLBCIK6zUBZZ4Br0R6fZma6EftUhVc0QvktQrp8tpvY5sm0bnjY6jZg7Raz42veAPeU4/JeOKsepINaJR5LROW@iX1qTF1Wug0FiGPB640OdPj9cNbwfntyyZD5kMDZxkXpyFWam6Ot6AMussn08PhatryP7ZgSBLwnMEuX4o767UPBE8/B8@@GoaGuFWIRecaQKi6/YZfEB@4tr@5y4c@Mzxxj1zegh4476DVeIEs5WHKPDhNQNNW6syAaVnTyw@@tCPLL0adqk7JtMZtrJskbgeG7Jhn8t0wtz0Zo4cvpssvYuHoY6NruwfsIAzDfLjYGNZGMz/LplAjcpGXO@ppjlhp4WcvwJ0GXEvAskA@pYzlkcefdMj79nB48MTZeSpS9un3QHux7ihxy2c2KCVMpEhqVe6G5nv5CvSuqY3Tj84VuW9xwcKBlhBbz6jIcMHZ@YWPivHPf2jR/W0vrIXhL7GeLmC@MnJk8fJ@d5PltgbuM7QkKLee8fHKdzb8tXjpd7R2I@gdvSc6croB/uqKi1h3@c2zQ6ukp5LUloF6cSA3igw4yf8wJdblauOMzK6J7OR8Rk0nijBvTsmX1iZyaf6udnHWsjKKwlFFZWVlUJOiizOhs624YbfVeV5Zo5QWnbok@aflctRUHPIpt3scu1h3Yz/dS2GZfyVCB8WSc3c5NaxKUPN6A/QlNa9vy9iqqquovOx3oNyZfmVhbUYYNn8sOWc32Eq2fA7L3LoJI@Bq2Tz1qXkRXkIojuNLxye9x3B2F65DGYdgNC5sLTCXxj2TLdlmstap15UIDYualsb5BvGHSakwhU@53gg9NI5vnBVPUt0yCjdkvCJG4myt/fg4LYIRz4t14f6@Olz9kz38HST9QGjGBt3wHiuGb2ScdwKj9ZbOZ3adQGUthZef7S8PlfYse52HXs2vX0Sjja3YtNOhxWHsNBGgQzLnJrL2qoOH9d6tnyZ0W1p830czmxBD46eeuMDev@df6aqmQydaYRfNcOtt5RMUMFZAk36DA/Ki3qdHISioYN6iwIO0tLe6GNjistR@Gjwsk790vatsKbtK0qrm5N1fqU1frk16d3wQ0eWVTLqGoD5NX4sr4Tejx3rYuAoe7preHcskwhq67JUXpOlckROvyllcDiUphh982plH/cx@J@bgfhWq6OJHT3810v5xzfwHZJ8z5qnBCc0JxJ2MilJi5cARHfo8b1peEQc31YGYd@@ZRv@7jHwCDfU@XvW8CQpUGUN3OkpEAjcSpiwazU1X2Y7eBR/BRoqiVJEJzqvJ0irwTYv/a1glYp6hdvhxIrI/K164fGb/AhJgIuH30GemHymss0x@GwGG8kYHYLO3jJSfqG1VfMZsCnp6M7eqr/DDlDavHx28Gz/@GT35PlxI9O8EiV/HynHzbYhtWCH8UfZrgh598kGlYofKEs7US1Ijg5oR6XZC/LFIGfXslZbyNo8U@IOxtm8tO10mjZUpuUrwE8WeWrkCy0kOnHYQY6pfPz9sBW@D9EikoqbHLRIaUKZVVhmWcIj3fMgW77/9SsiyJdls@jLE/bPAIVq03ecrp@iZ7DbnyDFR7sHj58f7bMAwTnTXJjd8aBWzvMjYrHhkQ0op55JazNqLO5HiUNZ1WrxR3EgTFyJswptY6XjWYHPIVhAHdwA68feYolNgg8UjIeFkv7P30xfxRVcZihB2HiAVJz5lMcA7AS3pv3ZT7r8@PLgQIrgLhR3SFKWNv4L/rbTFZtOkaJUMUerb0Sh48Jpf2l4Tvn8lhmBTq8Hrrygs6SunTMk0dEf/Hob/xioICFikODIYxyvwiOdoLN9buLmUo5DD09YWmRlnOKmU8UUtovXvQDPM52O0AfUJ/aYn2Lin3kQAz5SQoGSYpuELD9wX4wEjG9vACu3jb5pM8@GToAxrrBXwGc4JlThO5xluR6/ESUAze/5kQfjoRUJeONIJi99Ok6//7XvpvtVBuZp5gHYfsW39cD8q9z8RRrL@uaxTfP0o0jgUWs@1jzxkOZI78jNNjbfST4nFp4uFUhKZg6haM6J0hicp8DfMgjYOZxE4zMoKGAxKCV/BzlPz3CbCTzrrZJOIxthI6LQqlljypewXDvzrZAv5NQ0ICmfBwDpkOY@bs/jACWpAowvnJuj2ss2sNf2NhNRpzRqhSovzfSm/UVWfBkiuglhhYsBItdgEAeizGOAX92PBs1JUpUwKsqjuBpHUdR1oJ0hf2yP0G77hBBZAojFaWTgqb9TvOJo7M6CswvbeG1Q5AD/TR@QrEIrQyZJFPxNz0@dMbDMwnZvvukZl3DxNg0PBfP4FV50ZCDyoHKzNs336gU3Bfj1S8F6z0FlM9ebx2jZii8QxDGCqIjLWLbxBTsdn9rNNOdNBmz6I59lo8xsg/mfpPsreJbne/fmgXGJ68e9IbHY/WPbQeX5EWSGJbS0lk2rBWmepVxuaZb8HPnJQHbwGIu3kByIJhATHcN85Yy83b39g68ePju@cSgahYxfDwaSvL6dPJWVVKMZGuLRbC0WyYNH6eMnDx4FBTFHuhCRwKC9@DlR1@Vk3idGkPM11teztgzD67lbjfELvhHzOr5ZbR1qFOkGHmrmA9KldY7yI9qtcD1xrbSMWvn8OpTm8NIR0Ht8q9kNVBPS5VWjuV0/tWPxm5ywpCJ8EVO2sBKA6dTb2kwjs9/MHGYsvGrvBC8I8qJ1Mbu8LoqbWTybBze7jp2z@alEvkPEI5LfIBkQkYKSDoKurH2HXOuen52l8asA@Sk@0bNLIggXMusoHgF1EtwqiFJkfvKff@jdAHqmltkWgjNj@OF3wRld4bl3/LyXhCT458fzhBP@PYPTylShRQ0JCaUdwUqxdefoBfAkASo06mvPJtBDfuaM@HnCNHn10AhMRw6I34cTPgtusK9OhhCuR58jgwYSQXLLEBkoGQ9R5foTSAn/GL1pEg8qhPQaeJien3Fl2M0nppIyMKZdsw@yPSGlQKJ9pKpNFh61h5mmo/XsuEhlNi@FtVXxY9xAGCX7B523OJ0joDd0xbS7xjQRv4hLlSakj@7xixfncUlcxkt07qN/EGL3@gGQIfpFdb0k0cd@7QxOV1wmLcrlm1IC3K4D5icXBZeZlMvKwBPoTqoa6uLHY/cxGEGNSPSG@oglJjY/3UlhZE2cJuwUHYcj1/kBcTZLJqmLBB/yUBjF7JGJt98J3Z6xRLoGTICunt3FzxtzxBqqojTBTIlIbBMvGdoDjQtPSpEE6NVClAqBrSELQccBMOKVROEMDnHQX8ADbFw6I2uJN925QuMtDtKEcs3q91jkrqhFzVEslyt@gS5KxTID7rspDpU0gL0h5wJdHqjrn8QANIMOrSLE5oL8psSLUboxjsgn/hEOgE4scqhjcLIDA1jzIxc7Axd/iX0b6goeRlN5fvKoVZLSIguPgui7ZhfHA/m5xGGnzb9JAqppeiFovMr7aB9jNDzjq8XPmsAjqB5RhRGvidRYlAzXb0@d86aqruV6P6JfChAyhw2Av1@mFYDDw@yCmdklfsuF/c9/jvezionNnUK2ZZ0n4/lMFV5qNc/y7KPNU1nebGj5TO3@pq6PX5@KTE/nth6eG4Ne@6CfPhVFlmW5dHor/mjrmakV2Bevp1dZtfT6bKQWGsrraVMs1VJnzSl79uzzd613kjg9n4mnCcaKMcb2Dt@Kag47q7FKkZUZ/haeN/ii6xOXPjd66WJcZLHTU7x3VSyK6XQj3oR/8noJDw/UqCt1Zaf57p3UKEKmprPTGF5lyA7vkzf1k2ikSdOkY9M00@x05HW78HMGrMkv5I3xJ5lMyMx3kBvcrTqc9shtumv0@5N9fcbdzdgEP4/Gftwn33jx4gUaXtDD3hzFfNgcYpBGpaXnY0zLaH/2042r1OWz1vaffWuYNjbwc4if7149QfOxmv9oY@OjBw9yuRTQhpuffePZ13d3d3MPU/lnjfxOTs5sbP/pn2xsaNq2lt5oep7ajDfOzj4XtUxOVP7sx/HWs2df87x69v/45ru6iq8ivM6xZPDJMhWM@C7BT0Ud64y9geesx/CfzG@6EbOO5nbvDYu9iQGXx2b014rNy2yDqfWd4n/5/uHr2DhW19IvXPiOY69jhVKMG8EAtmxgO4/VY9sYrHAVm6VrtRoYi//l30L8@lcBDvrMtuFVzwewCrNYXa5RlLexegEMqqZBuv/XN78ZYR4uJmqkxgXPfdaAR8wVNXGnCc8WPdsCHsAlZ9Lpa/ynlu6p9xizx4Ox4eDH5B8bPkyv2tDrPmokk8mmIsOjtChSWlW1UxqwibIWjbfE5s6Mu7CoW8gnvgv4vYgRTwFTEV9xs@9ArMYdXlwP92LJU33xD/0cCbHCxn3jYb0OojBbz27Vk/RsnFYqnPxpViyJjnNf3IIiy9DrMYMPCMw6CI5MSRNTqdT9FmiVGtJUnvr0i8VPxXgs9nJO0oCyMTa3sahTzCclC@vgLxBuH58//1///Ad//n36@wH9/gOeVWZ3zV56i@HV3Oy8zh9Wr4t1V7w8Jct9lqmUKqV0i12dJrYa9eYRUzMfv43ns/FjbCRUCnUqBSOcsfCp1/EVoIG2eoy71Llp7ub71EMLhZhHWR6O@ZKJMT8RaIL9JV1y4xxkbD3I0ZKncR8KSdSKZbFZ1/LaYV3MqCIVW5kNNj3m@PIgtgPPBvzRPzyhdQNHkTfIbSPwoVA3n40QldufBSyFWKORbhpNUGRZPQByf6OyUaoUKhoUymrA1VWgY@fL6HFfKSolRQM58q6xwY440zdZMnhOk7c@zxWl5RvJ4OBPlp1pTIj9Azx1gcUu4Wm@22q8Ax72k274FTa5LTfrSR8j@Cit@82kfHXVUL5IVqv@/3Y9NFbp4SbISPNKlre/AFiNm1A5UHorrS@2AWxyu7Fdc/bop7SQ1nI858QLzv3mF/XG9iIIH8r9@0mUufcBTn0TuFVKJjdleaOxMg8AuAlqyvY2lOTV9lX9qrF9dbW9Df/b9L7yv@B6tX3jnz7zZ0WYuT/Vn9NGun6aPvX5pwl2JV1HFyV9CoY6fCEctEdCDDSUqRDbYluxEVOLWTAxo6Juadl0fvpRYR80o0ZTxq5MTW6ohXxT5iLrpcIqMj/pXC0VJAVlUsvptXBzosJeCrGX77/8n/F3@v7L38cGH@pnWYilt7CfUObdBXg9sdmTJ0/w98S24R9@T/hjows6PEE3m79sHiIIEzpzl2s1AwQFE7VSQWwl1ZnGYttioYii4pduPPF4/B@91MrFOO9V436@lx44/tKy5x/90qpHiL0tY93veIxnT4iRLIBigapUl@X69hCXceFotYwdg89qn8vPd2Xsyepjmn/o8F5a7WC/Vi7XPQ9VSCF2iVDar/Hv8Rv8ez3Gv5MO/h29xj928gb/jsb4x5608e@Zh38nr/Fvt41/J0P8e/Aa/56M8e95H/@EWA309s2djJXpZNQz9QwMJsu4LDPIDNQudioyBsvMMjOWGTpqF0wG/GXAZGZ6LNNnGTtjqyp4gmHMMmM09eDTh78eQHHhz8SFAGdqpsMgFQsbIbrtiL5vQSZKp0IDeqPiSwM0bEVVMkrBbOIh8Q2xqZVLTMGCUVqNl6fxJp4@qpVzrD0zNk5fspgH2nk1lj49TfNxBqblqnie/NVVq7X/9GGrlUZhdvrEOZz/Hx4Oo9a1/8ND58mhM3Tg//Dw8Akz6sn7Sfk@PLV6ctv/7MTq1Z3Tiow1PxA2sfT2zmk9K6O5kATBoaFb8gOfOUT41jdOhTgDpeeiSqpV9eK8elElQ2gFQ6saBvCDcQM4Vn2VDFyqgW52Ac/5BTniC40XL05DEzekX1ycYhcD@o7hP@iuUet/hX/z/13/T56zRKMJqlLi8mo7QY@Ef5J0eXV55b/rUiLhWxLb8IcOYMcol1d1NFKgSzA1ElJTurribvBOSNscYB3T2K5T5HlAqP2xME1Kl78S/3W/mLb/nOI55fp80v/0dJrJSNV2cC4yTnjpb2nuVarSLTeb7Yba/NMf0@nXOxIFyueqVXWLcYuW06rVXGArlqrVUmDZTCTKN596ZkctgK6Uy0lStQqWnQBsBqwh2BKADSx5gGp4eofqfTV2eXBI50KDmMjHJMwRFwyJDB0fjzeRxMWKeO9ewr/hdGdXundPK2fevg1dRiNwUhecWq2u6bZa6J59@1ZsiTQJX86DPVN6@xZkWVxy3MRTvMAGEkrIKvtIq1OaZccFQhTBm6lpbY7FQPf08dhNvDFHKRGXNHmiRPdLZDKOexr/2fe@9a3TeK0myiK55lQEgKmw/PZ2IVevF3JgLpSAUuLmJb9qpZ8sq9LVZlrk1GDiZjzme6mlosRlYxz9oWFkO3Wo4B4@7PIqRsXOcnkpAdJVAlXtKoZ/3Fktl7k7yxUSpWTZ/6ttSKwOWgT/w65uNpnbKm7dbzL6my57UCRXL42aelW7NCo4YnhV7fi3B@IeSOPevWwZaFrKVE@FVuvh7sluq1UTRRHbQ3ihIwl3AS8tGrnxBhV4vtxsYP6ap/F4pXqfmEMt5VksXvXDyXFoJVipTGQQzB5ucIa8C6o/jrAhaPTFl@CPJG2AYwxb9Pnv2ePdvf2TlLYNSpH2aHcvpR0/fxBT0Zqf28k7i/aj/d2Hh88hwrPH@7vH@x8ffLb//Bm4e@xi/gQS2H/Pv1HTEvsFeyG8ct/ohqEbE8NoXUwmF6/ZK9NsmUBYa2KaptN3mWe0DMMYQbDgqcKvY3r6q1e6O6KHvf/Rd97/6L95/zvfe/8733n/Oz/42Zc/@A78fgK/7/Hv9/5NOY/vn335z373/W//Djj@B/j9Efx@@rMvf/Ob/Ef2P4bff4q4/bH/i4TjPwFg/crPvvz@j3/25a/@EH7/0v/98Obv1366/PeDb6/@Ybzv/@76MN/7t/D7PQ4rCPu93@Zu@L0R/rd5uF/94fvf@Hf8/0/9PzT@zvvf@GN8@ZZ/@sM//U/vv/XvNa30p//6/be///7b33r/7e@@//Y/1t7/5r9WM9HX777/wR/81R/@3l/94f9A/z@h9@/d5f/9D//pX/wvf/G//cUf@r@fwu/fgemnf/HvgWH/9g9@hP/f/4O//aMf4f//9K/@9g9@/W9/5X8kw29xw//9L/8Nf//1r/3Hv/kX3/2rn37zb379p3/zW3/wV//7r/6fv/kf//q//f2//u@/hY6/9dO/@qNf@ctvfecvv/3P//JbX654f2ft@8s7uH/5D@BydzzvAucu@fpQly9/IXz@PtSYpwJ8Atz9T97/5i8Dg/8GY@@/8xNcyQu/Ff8/0VQK8xNu@/@AQbuZZ/TJgAl@v/7@O99DEv13QCL4D@n13dCy4MMt351bgKz/4lqkmFFZbDxLWim5BT2MrXLZb0BD722K@bMv//mPwyR@eRHqgh@k@F2UVAt@30UZ9/5H33z/43/8/ke/9f5Hv4KtmZwrp3ZTsrp@@SI0gXL@DuEwYOEu4SDg59iaTpM06ionP/8cHD/3PT///HNh@jaNS8fvvwXXz8mJP4x7gR/zvQI/3x0XvUbDcGMmMG6i89to0kiGJCabJFVgK9BT8lk2TfoYTXFQD7/gDoGmW2Sc4ptc0Xsq4Gv@PzdOBZbEMPzB23YCIxn8eH4S3CjkIZnkdBrQixQnxpWVLe5CE1KUbq7MMAfTaXIKPVIwQApJ8HqQZLVaLYkRaxwfsHLU6iVGqCSTNcg3xuZxUq0Sgpg@ICgQs5Y8Yq2t2pRHTCK8ekCOpIBOR6KqiclS7SEkWJs@ZAgLgRPYly9r9VJtWkdw7zg9ktPkA8IJgdWS0/o7sNcIZhKHpR6@A1RKtWSyXsIEMZO8eFItXkh5yhzlPcmSfhnAF8d4d@4z9pGolkQ@ObKBBOOh8Z2ch96h6bod8D9NbvnZof/ASL8tIvgGJeWnwrj/DqmKO1x7xAAAV5YVRWHwwynAHXYfvKccVJKShU@SQ0gSRxAHhA7AhlgWSSrfJFkg/Vht64OfZF3gudnc3BRidTErHtJkURJ67e5ZhV@X8pZ3jSpMLJRFdDZoETnPnbH5jIYdth5uwVuF//0NWtudZFVCazOOw4NxxtNjHyX57/79LfYR5J6@czeBycmsk8NxeszodjIpapBq3UkKX4B0E4B9CdBbQZnWaIoqKaRSjCm1GPqxw8NDHzVy@KImJIH7tayKdpxTmEwmMYihKCkllfK/Cn3JQfENCvn6X2UTaU7DmUzTclXo31QZOrFod0SFfis6vnv3DgqL1ndUDqBHyfylHlquRJ7gwHfUWtYs2IKg5coC704ztcAvNE/QfYcSkwSWYFuSwFcCcySCJxHXSqU4miQoEyWxFaz8KahCMLQYqyOiwcP7eKW8FHjuHbK9wydP9p@ejJpNJhh0EaXRGrlOx/C8dYI5gfF2nz7kGwW0cgHRiDUamPJJRUOxJOxXMiQ0Dx4eHRxXGKeJX0KJEJJUpRFknxRlVYiNRi@2Y/7qCBFvRnHEY3xX5vlPaOUsJlivCrGOgd0SYDj8Z1Xhidd/4EyhL58SxZRawC6aRAOvTPi6U6nU3qm5ogBfsk8YnuHFN/xC7cTl5Mr2NhFNqF/KNG6ORijgglCv@8uMmCrUj/dPIMLJIVO1jMKgp3@ZK2q5fC6vZQuFfFFTc4VyrpAvZaGtKWTymqaWc7lyqVy8Euqfs6mCuMpgtmqWYffHg01c3COeZsQIPTYbmRT@adksvAFiSs0Xmxsb1qWMCJ4SW1ziKq0rsF7KSIGvwMOErwjsK@AED6SBS6@Yv@7t4LDqLz7CozUSfAWSqOahckvCKTASByeMok91BNUHOvuRnxDb@MY3xqxeh062fPBIiIGUGrBgAY5sdpWBQnzUnbgG@fYZ65qfmXhfjtI1vZGlz6BuZhQhdnV11QNIB4@YVtfIymN08X3VIZc2mK@muvD/P7/IE5PlurA9qgMzbqdHYNTBmNtO62BsgzG/nW6D0QRjeTttgnFSz6qZ7fQE2ghhmx9KxXDPa00cG1M8A4@7iXXPsHoK7jOoiZSAJm77hzzW/Xh13LDh6N0abozEhfYJ6VLo1rpOhy7oErpK2@nOFG88s3BBvuW4tTioYvHAw8Q7T3G7WK3BmsrIGUGDqeWLyYaaAfmMP7WU0lJdpWMZuruTr@RLaAlnTnbymcqFaXedC@XzJ48/GY9HRwat@d/JlStdBU@ewD3iO6VKPt9sNEQx2aBkmnjfH6@c8sYGMLShd2X49hx77MlaqQmRu6Zbq8XjO1lVrWQzJeEqzLwAZMMc1QWMl8ScpJB0lz7vV2zHhnpWSekp85JyXen1eldbl8m5RdAvZW4DelzJeqp9GVqrciRchU1Ssjn3BBe9B83MpT9pVBG1fEmsNqpze7EgVptXwv2h0TV1XOd/mrm8GasA8ohDjUFCp0y4qriOM660jZ7jGvOAWbUQBOQI3QyQE6/C5E4zmOLlzeQKGAhoyCkHfMoPAKvT2rYGiNDmPrSMjeZ2cDQY8qemyVpWzqqymsX/Wwwa/t89vAb/Gr4hVlYTTnB77FOQpNBU2OwxnkQ@dtiJ49Clcw@MzooQewOdFvHtuY7n/T3CPNDtM@710ORnUoVen@h424Q3NMeDFSGej4a4i9Nw/8Eg7A/bgCBVawrwAF6u5TjLAhTZ82crcvkkPAUSiMGPgYTgRwcff3IS@Z7s7@59IhTYg8OnD6998n6gPHu8/@gktBa5bxA1H4L4@v7jx9et/ieGSgUODm@wfDEwqAKuAr4HXap7vjFfmBszaHzBN6iZXrgqle9ErAgnwa41naGwaBuswzfWYh@PDiLxVT21WBaEEbOdC1bMsK5jWTpeuNnbAMeBjrtxDFReLLoXFpO@cFyre2F2jQ3hCW78Kat4qyAiIXwCQIaTDu36N8cCHmvVxaswcTKibU0MNsHrZlc4wged0Oia/QE0BRdOEEBo6zqD34c@EN@IPuP1DmOeBrnd8LFuBhdigj7WY6XqvXvqMxe4up6pVPrGWaW@PwWmYs@ByXU3L2aVjviIKa2Yzvpmw2uOoKyyua2CisoMaJ@gc7FSqnTEUAND7bihgQZ2mknrOceuss20M6p78cyVcQWNSjG5k4NWY9zrVKGtylegDP76X/zk7/7k12nlDxO20vCKqaKI65E3VEEhpVcrl/KlclaDZMqlXF4t5PMpVUtBn6JYhkQzakktlPJlNVXKlbM50CLBN18uCjG@2Cu9RSDhWwGwdgcvwtsmvVkZ1IUYn51ibxK6xGJ6aJ8w0YA4Il597o1pw@OWWRO1HFMzDLpMAFFnHRZ79Ggv8@iRKD5AC87J72VEsYuWfCmTKT4QRYN89krY9osOj1PC80TEMbdkMg/2RHHCAeBRnKI4QMt@AUdcRNFEy97uo0eYTg8tGsaHYGfch1uswFKEYDZaslkashHF1yE4CLfLE8oRpvtowTTR5xH32QM/Ufw4wCeTAQhHPByH8EmQ191dUTzglt1d9NmjjOc5qp@iZZceUXTBAvVDFPtg6LtQM0WxDUasJaLYAVNnpoMbXjuI5zXaY10UZ5xASCJRnFJovXMmiq3AHZP55JNP9MG4a/T5M3P5twOogY85new/an/8cbvfb7uz3f2Pj9Bnb@8TvTebuO1@24/WbsHjQBzwORvOrj@A40GrpVtLfT4FH/uaT2vWMhC3lv4acPKfPiYybO2Bzx74LJvY49DgGULQNj4PhvB9oLfJJ3jIh77TdlusIqOi@kl3B0OdoWt8U0O94zpVtE9rG4zFE/HUrFHINKvkwYagaGaqV3RpcALfOnbxpctZY1rLNGvTWlHjK0J6CfF0quVNMbUx3FHL@cqGvqNqueS0gtuenV6cxWV1hyXUe1tvWOKptKNlcxXxdGdHFhtqc0dTS5VC8YutiShKFXzvZIsVCJiJQwcYX1Kj2Nwp5iNRisWkntYqxaJUvQJyjKEVbaNwaSUSF4Z@JkmILnbUIAv8yuIZ5dOs9hLT1LTG8WIzqTqtqVV@lBjL3IDVxXMrJ52x43KIfQA33clU6FJkUS2XREg/nU5IEkgmEiLwna8Ye/G1k7OTk88FFF11vwP5jN@0WfWtH3@yp0Cf0rfheZPKI1TzHVfZQ8Gy4MOPQwycTkAbVj6BphB6AoEbbkVxHUvZn0K3HvsKgUdwipjin/2knHyyAOcYes88ZdzJW6XDKuyOwfA4TrPL9FodTHqXJQgrpksX1Ai36vVaqzbk9xrXw1ifMjqrcg7mwOO4h/uLKfolbs/wPVq1zFW1XZvGpgCnVWOy@nLodF9qyU61i6dwPqg9wMjVFnzbVaNm4O3OYkys9nbsGmMT29N7xjPDxd3yB4eboBLgno1EjxnSJjulu6D3UGe@kusus@eYPZ0ME7pcb0uLThErkibxtSDLl7SJCKfKr6q9Gkt8IVVfg9XdZImu8kDayVW7iQesJYFL5mXvZY9prJCr0vV4CYQElYhoQ3csS7X6p6DFcMBnlQog4pfxGcDElACs2SUPXRqZV9VOzWIJmU2ZROTJVfu1BsZ@i69tWRSbstx42xTqsvxCqEM9rc5ies2btOnoZpZpq1qmUJ2Cm1rMVQdQsPoX06pbG01co2qB1R9N4Xul9CqQE6gGYN68Tbz/5W9K23K@xt2qBOqtBYpDS2nVplUbD4MBlqhla@CRbOQyKehJwquYggZZA0WgkMqmcim5iK7QGqfyKXBUQR1IWAmRMTGVmWYUNaUaagpq/0uz@5JJqbMEKB5EMrCMnX28WhpcoJCQK8kKX51JSW3LYlAKDtO3ZWJTkBRVzBjQfMBGZmqAoI4M3aIYkiSz7FbC2kxgmM2TyWi/0axU9qejr4FXQn69U0gWM8k3klRNbEg1z3gt1KtCHaUK5Xq0ATzrDzQxbzJsQBmPN9WiVmk02pjDYiaVzWQhe2brbX9brIvNVGajoEIJXTHSYxgXGFyXmWsjc7cWas54TztTy1pVUGhNBaWoJrSytmJwURJwNZ8PUBj5wg4pzBKnYrBbMBGPF7V4XIpXcUh6Q/RHEkHC8SvfQdTG76k7IuhPYkUsaxhgLihpQ1gmqkJdCdgzZ7myELsUri6vtqFrmabFdaAcsg0yyUr9vhCrMAZ63Kl/5Eh6g7EPXbOX3K5/wb@nuC4Y4Ap0mBsojbSSxjCxP8Q@w82vOywOiOnusKFp2WZDK0L7BjIzCKppahUH3GO48lipA@W9S8BvO1nHfSOfstlMT8oBZe8x1k9uCpTp2HWy79Z2@0e71cC2h2N@p4IoitW4GLuMx@JX8CfE7tNmFY1vVmGxyHYVvpi1YwB93sVIYrC9y2DQp4JXiiT0CpcPjab07qlpXZayMu/bg8C6uoptpqlE/DX/1U9fankoI9sJNgFAHwfHUKDpyudxwDKWfjnyvqGVsk8ODu2H7iOD8T0ApVxLrMdYRpVxSX214rvm@XpfsVzSRO0sFWP3Y9UYO5PjaoX2CbDRcfmL4helL548P3x@@EiInW683XBwMJsFZGHv7K9@DQLGs7k4Y6e12LSWq/qLp@p1Wd3W8DCfIquAsO@pBTnzts7Zt04eBQ183v/yD3PT7RLYNdBeK1CE@aRWr6tbGpNio/df/j6e4nC5/9nuYxb39Bn7uz/5sVb8uz/5V7QkKX5V9WjktBiDkGhUC8XY5eXo8vIKHu6XjzVjHKlcUQIzH6VXY/OtCJW0rm8Vkzntvl1N@2HVoirFPDnmz0UU8zHvre@lZUrgFUwWkJNYwCKI7R@ZeU29v41MoYY7mNh8TtrwysAVpScv3zIGlk692@@bGpnSaVZ5J7Ptd/I2e4eD7e/kDfayVscJYhX3PQXDy1v1eh2hsHg9md6KMy0Pfo2rajPJaIAaOnxfGMaWfbrI0acbuJp80WnLhj9jy6M/jBM4eGANbMbWK4@JiS0pne52/TN/tg2WrwMrbKUBs1Pp/S//pqYV/u5Pfu1t623rcw06ceVyQdViP1d//nMIsGbvfdADo3F43CSPhrDnxlZcNw3dVCGGd5D3GA8f9OOw54bqg9m3oXuONuEcVR4qpRY/0KmboGBbuDU3RQo0HbciVQUhVDRJQXb7nRTBYFt4FQBUU@FS@Ap6QbvKaiA5ha/MQYHDEFpSp9PyrIk7ohX@CYqnNlPsHkSBFL6CZ2Vt0JZiX/zKILHSWzejcpQ9ohqpR2xoeB6evAUNivAViOIf24Y3HOu4@x1DmjbIewWDEJ7k0W1A2k1I2@IRWuSaoNzzACnGseORbFCiha@AXkBUMEFdYOY2BKiCjPkKEADykPABm022zbISuzSTyer8WK8rXOuMx6Tpwc5bAaMhtC7u9A4iVzEcOIHyjhcFIV/4JQyaWsQxAMJh8LnYGqj/GJ1sqH/R1vg7gwJYdAxNgrLG7t2bY1WrmV2JUY4Q/pk5wkEoKgd7Oa4ALOg6fdStiCmGB6ZVA9eQ7YDiSUIXuE7mJ6VVI1GZiNYrQYD/OzMtcuS1oiKPKmbALy9eKzpAMoiMZOdl2GHbNaZqRYmFyHcA9w4hRYd0hf3B0@lHivZ54HkFGP48FhzDDYLoJDqw5/Pt9a3XDFrACZ6BjAfwcGHgb5nmR@ygQDsYB7HDWJAV06LQPdOFvgrNBQfndSWyqoTR5uebER60elnLMVxGnJfwQ7EwNIOvjidT@els0OkaHQcK1Bs5Nh1lRcdu4Apt4AiQUf6JQBztiX2BZ@b7ZUORoxh5dBoQcj5iTEdz0WWDFBcnV9sudGgD2qSY0VdYZ9hlWpkliNHo5CI7BCdRJEK4DYov0rhtGUNA6dgwaH@MV0mn@6AgTdp0fNMTE/hq8MiEVsX20v69jukL88xMn@CZv7LTw200fDN8DHUqrH58Htc/KslynDNmmWcGH69NLBwl4DFQ/UF/TQFl5z8gbAWHhrVsimXAO8VDwa8InyI3llKRuBuJmXTzm1U3Ei0s0bfUyJgu3tl4rtsR@tLzVvB7u97MCw4joSM1wK6EItfwjyGoxXGDcXi@huAfq1KjEz0UHLMfJaDvGRxHgkZQy41zhv1WAdsYEJqdYGM/1mLI7VeoAaC6BzULTyYbuxU8jgIwcbuJDlQ9X8Db7COW1QQMyM@K8c91ARhY9LVF6OAHUTEf3rgLBaPwvWMgV6B2DrvghxuhffbD@AF3o5lOjZuzN9vwwWGjQ2nVGK8WgSUfsWDtQH6mrG@AZwEwXILJRkJMAtikKIkcdBj/enTO7QLJkgq7CSnFEIJPaoBCqkJwqSuLHG4vgMcD3eOnbfpnmF1cXCh0mN7ENRXDwwPfPbypNj3qm6AeO@mxMRz5V2uZeKWiD3dukvk9D3h/8c6Ubg4u35vxryD0vJq/6iIR73lxbBzP8Tzz/pAO4cHTbzxiqEcm3YXQSfgLRTj/ac3UZcB/FeQ/uRS/QiCMIZhpapbqpABYqt05S/UuulXf45wqJACHUjQCRzzA0g0sQy8wmaNeGMIZ036IwN62zmj@ESCJfBR1njTPYRByFlh9@8icQiTbuGC7rqvPEuQvYWhk4MSM1B42g2affMAIzQy75KcpmtPGrLkQfRpGh0Yt6P0wF0/YES7XA@VHa6L/lPtPwX/K/afzRINkG9MmV8nQ6Qqzg1yPB7MFIRHMLAhzxY@hnPsQZNCxmcpBYMjZgtsV/Do1ih3Qm9ugHGsBYwBPjIDgRiLd@OK0cdq0PeNiq5lM94HZRSIElDiAbjSJphfd0IzUt86tkeMtONl4Hh@0Sj7e6NQZ@NzAeQXzGBYQMQanl4lHqPWH/qw9Vwj8DAME1MPAE1WD3XHClKrhUa7kCYzTEOc05og1fGSapH35Xr4bqEuc9JywUUDNCCB0D7MEaIIPC2oOv94jkA4vXLzFPAgr040EQzzKJ96MAyWvVRUua6pUSBGsZDlAE8iO6mrtelYCfyiKxjWvSDav/PKPor/xwej3oF4sx54YljcYVSFaVXAZGqgQfnUhqrJ6LVKugEF6S7cMF1qufa6f@q01JLOVDroZPB3MgneBd5YmIoXfkXj50A410RYrISvMajXI4qzGqyWvFwFJOcHDaJ4fbRYwgh@fCxCAkVkazfCjTaPRprUaFxxsuiLaRQTJKSE55VF46OkKJJt@NOg9hZddY/E0QTvFRW8iwFN5Mwpq0EhkeHEpTk2/wmPGcMLST3Muc4gLfB5CFRv5rNNcmnojgnREaF0DgIx4A0CX3xRWEa4LPFUObaGM4qQMZBS3@WzAZQUwGIngKj@KMxEyGfWBQeEXk9QOQN0Vkw1BVGmIF/8y/CemAsfgp950zCyGVBcdM6lrf/8gjk2kbKSCRrQPNZNDgYw9mef@Fe8LOkcML9UcOKDVtS8clliibIN7OrgdPt22nHZ6qONyELw/KLwzXgr6Dzg9wu6PnLE@dnK5Cu80mcR2y9LnfQazbzt47HjkCF7Q9bqO4dnxMRRqx@nbpmek8JZ6rrIbtDiBn0ouRPVk3@h4guAPR/JuLILmfIWqbquFNxq2WglcyiZVwvWytLIN2TMeF7D/C6ZIfBBPPtDDUcJpvzI6Y@l2mHhatB/txOycJQ5HvmccEtllIMM6oP@D7wA0GOY5854jnVuLqnR7nKD7CAbO0OmD1jfxFAFjXwN/MIeNCOmjEeGSYjp2aSuRM8OpliQ6KV3yo376wVHZp1pCl8L42iKABWKkmHudxkhZd0lyrZXJ8WhBescfju9xFN/j9fhSL/w6zrxrXuOeH5Z0NjGHAAHnaGRvRwOzDnKrewOdBVRCZ9SreIQ7o9il5VZdxHQXgu76wZUe8EcqtHlgCxH/bBX91xdgEH3/rsWn4zWvxzOQN0NcBZigWwm8YJ4zAcEPJEmILUkuZO2Hd0wLwuIlPY9QhQA1lgSXjUduQsUcQbfbCw@CDwDfwvO4auoG39NSqhr3XIKTe55iZ9rqInrY6hqWPjO6CT9kKgI3yPERdNhIXt0t4yjoSOg5vK@XgLZLCn2hGUei80CVFSyjp84laTVb8SBmyD00Uk4YHqymH/rfEM04xFfjo9XQD4jHYzgce27i8OdoNprxU50tfsGHL0d5@8NLEvfh304QoIN/lk1qnqy0TnweJcIs3aFFCMMqi1nGQ1cDiHgKzM0y/DAS3Z5TKNxIpFpQysLiDQXLS9xcV@IRrgh4kk8h3Y0lb2O6O/NchNU4sLkI2/uwJuQGZFya0ekkohC5y9oSc@wbMgHdaJzOXtGqtJYI1DAmSbqxSd1t0i8kAXvGB/DFAafP4IsA@8a4xRkqyBuOafm3vDDyGeqjiNbiu4CSDlAiVOQk99GIhBICMwS/vArT7KxMs3Mjzc5CmmENWEwyEkjoLCTplwIWz7oisIzeeIV0Ri/sO8NnndiGx3Z0F0crLuNmvGKmWPw8XgGBHDfilf0ECOV4N155SAYvXjkmw1m88ikY5nUr/jZeCaoFBnDBSob76O6LcLR34pW9hHQljPUzwwvSVeKVsEwhzA63EkWAFJhv0Bpxis12/GyOXQMaNlIqUww5xkth94nGYVL0y8A/v3OE7i5ATxzj3KLALMnUhUYj0mLwdKDZCM7GXlKTK35rvn/4iJY2hUEwmST08aJxCDyo4bH4ojDiiKEvzWjAFxBEuVlZjhGLtGR3RMdPHTiUCnkxfaKeQvpAN0H@DQjcnCdCF8348YPyWgTBC/BueGLkVXjeQCdIjjDCOVlpCVpI1JfxNZnCsl7ExS/9aAnRWPdiILwnOQjCS4nARmQ66HA0OYeJjZzRIpOQLy6EN6NxaFCOV0rk3mvRSCr4NXOFNzn7OUPBEK380rrsROIhagsiCD0bmSavZWG7QLIYveayLqKp8soHKERkDtRwo3NGl/g89I0UjoubFLUVq5qhIC5PkiTXopiEyAoeKDTRxzz1sPO6j8cMfVj3NYg5xbGWBAKIxAxT4fLV@QD93eH6e6BQB0S4lsAyxXp5U3pTvV7byl7D3Jone7MA0TPFHkpLlaMwhTnJoXcQ0czX8doNFR@XfHAlnycaQr@m7QdkC/sEt9Dtet@Cw0ItwT1fdDzTwPFMW02omxqJda4ESouCKflweMZDTOdZW48rz/iyIkYfGt/WrQ8uYHexgKOFh/AoA@41kvNa7k5sWuUyr9sgtrkLilS1wrggp@nSsJjnjiDuaeo2nLYFh8PW0cPDp4@/Do1usViU/DZ6NscPay2OtYbtOIdM66TD9mBJt0VL4b0cONmNw/F0J/nGqS3ekCVcWIMyoEMqAfv5dVzyZVlEnl@ruxCPh41Q1Id1Nq8G@oJUQlVHxybb9Ok6BoIY48SW7gMJ1Fugd4p6axLdQNFq4T3UrRY1X60WLl5qtfxWDIsmmBGXfh7bSE88l@7B5NenXAgCnQTAHh6yF5/snrCTT/bZo@d7n7KvHz5nL3afnuCO7mfPHzw@2GPw2396vM@EhZWSeNUUdiiBrg@NjoE3AuJpbDlGkPec0YzLncSexN2P9SH7xOkYOE217enD@wNuUWxjXOex9qE7OsMxTJOuExuaY1xvQXdhQTcWlZsubbTDZf0MwrahTzvEPu/Q6Zo9E8IK2PcdmYYX7PdilgklCPI22Gab4koSXntFS4fogjpcgXUB0XUIj3M3AEbn66/oqm/T4xGMrsJ8woXPB1PwZP/oyTHDMwP2Dp8@PDg5OHx6zB4dHoH12dcPnn4M9Dw4Pjk6ePAcvSjgk8OHB48O9nbJgSOQURju2n818cZrUVAwOFGlc4Yz33Sje2hbHPVGDZ5d6LTl0GPxiY3Sx9Qt843RjVeFiYfqC25zpKkCltjcPfr4M2jzmfEaZziDqWBafyA@9@j6tc0M26bUoLLUob5V/eoKzZ6sSjQfMZwxvI3BqNIG/QSZUywATot4uqbBxD1co4Jj33wfP9XlADQktAGwEVSwYKXG6BaVeDy1TSDrkFrHcvAkRp4aX0ToWzDq/WCpSVUgivlrZRAobl04sHE8SK2GDsD34KD5yY5dHoBlQwcegOW4A6qiB7h2hOX9EJPx4QTFMytwh1fD0SOaFmbF0OGBTr3Yko8TLzcqUp2Ft1DhqQYW3ZXDR3noDj/d65gmRfEoPN4jY1m8Yhj8BjOQiXwqkda2QUgRhE0Ppxr8ZW/8qk/0BW7AdUJ6b@yxRE1S2AkuDjJsk99S1Ld0my@Bmi/dId5jJTy3puavuDXD231oM8jIIQbEm8UW8QjjPfS1QuOu8SDmgxsp6v4aSbphL1iCdhsCD24g8IuAAUDyQk@nQy0V7SxFME7PZ@WE5wBH4rjtu2h4YOfupGMsRPBXbSVemW/eSD6RUwv9pGCdImEHRfTGcEGtpKnMnuNCHSexSvehoBTsDJzR2ORlmFjMAc04UTMHobFhg9Re1uoLqSEdrqdoO3Yk0TZw8YpU28CUd0mVOJ7PnYfia345JnA@NMJ83R2io7fxRvP53FkKJ5EuDBx@AUWY5spx8HM2Jky4/inMZcc7hvfrlWr1hw9O5XcvU3jJHhcL/F7LYNEh/oAxMS2oHjTPRwsWXdS7/JoWXI7kTdoY21@D50tLrOUBMOgHDkzo191vVUM/vtz4pjtul7nuTo5v39Z4LBklk3/VqTdIzKVbijWCJFMUp8n8JSAR2QnIgqxPBC4pghnK6/u4RQZLoQoUsVGOYL/92tVDvggJctee9ECy@DdA@sUdwpdYnVZUzC/ExU0u0fJIf5F4UEvWpfR8QQmLkDMRiOhUAFmVpMiyFGqvboB7uB4cyO@7gyutxY43Dx8E7eFaaB@Em5xcDYs3SxFYdwf7bg1Y3rj9QmAh76nVgHkjeRNayOkhc6Y2Y@Fq2vUp/j/FPe1WG7mSv@mnEG0S3NBu2yQQgjGJAZN4lo9cDMnkGOJp7LbTd4ztcRuwJ2HP3f2xL7D7fx9hX@W@w/21T3G3PiS1um1I5mTPmZwT3N2SSqVSSSqVqkq/zPQdjT0Ag2svalA0UKO2mz4dUau4x1ku4JhgYoGofrZfPT0VNu9PoCzMe7hlaMtpEGEvinextW3Yp8nO00KT3ixr4Ul9SVi0qX@PDea5xHtgqpAyiCvpoSeL@OrnTjjhWU@uLCRCkPU9TYiKcknsvqg5KGpIwPewBwRk404zGmjNbWaGF58wMo3AJd1clo1NG36ysOa1G@9VHE1NQKZNkN9Fz5L5/feB5eMtVQ8LWBhIBxvcBkka1hvYJ9Sh4iFk9LxkDz7SLapL0cieBeyMoh0afhWSEvaPMxQxEgvhLAsb07oUjiVqLB8vKTGHDBJxGfDR0lMmskUzJKgpnr5smx3qxIteNrkEgZCJN@29NrkCil/el/Td79l4nSxrgdwca0uETUNheYnaWQm79HCmJ2gLvZGeHtJVwWz7aFW5/5@qeJVI1KRoPrcxKhEgb6yvP/sW7HQrVPHcj8LmNSQ9f46vh7C/j0FG04jU@8C5tWNXpccM8Ajp2LReDZhUQRB15qwpibbTYmTiB7iwXgiQwXjjeHlhulZHTFK4zYfOK5IJnbLMtMEYwrqhPGpmqH//eHU4IX@zvsU/Xh8PNsyEpoP3aJV/NBhFQeyVZwRUMT6hK2vyWzAa9Skb@zNdI5QsuTE96mxH3nZs8MqtwkQ6bzNb0pHeSWx26ypdA1VC6kUP7ytF7V4prd7LFUtmUw9qh1WxQnEAOwldpD2yHWPuWQz7jyFAczDpJXD5IB@@J9EW/AccXAUSyETefFmijfNN3IgiIDU36A4YaRYq59Ziuvc7UcvvY3QP134SCdt9CgVJC1s9OXDmadYLpUR5QC4a9rNQyrVznk1F4RsqdBFSEgT3Jn43Fiz01FCWko/cMu/ni5uFjZcWta7vjt3rxstLd6VVtgUsvn7/OroZ3bV/7Q4@33ZETwz/ejVpTX//TYj15@IZ1LX2lGPAFjfKeQqg@QL@boqXBeJcieArimd7YQvh8c12QiyLeB9eWhR8qxttmrfQQyLFpWLlWnEhutiNy9eNjctyv1woXTf6lyV08huvlserxdUsfngKqyjMMXwy3xhf4ppqal2D/q3AC0/pYjrpGiLINQS@HPmjcHBYOX6T0MahAIAqMGnrTQp1vqt0Aa3Z0PfE6wd3WakmcwVyrIUCkrVAXkFFdG8nfTKqY9ohYAa94oI0G03o79SxFgrezXA8oBQV4g9ZS3wNv1oLyo2pQBoFyNIIVSBAuqI9msR5sngwxF@nbEWdK7K4VkTfSccA0cCSNB3aF7aNPoWIqPTlalxakRf4rc@IBF7O@5WKie1tuqoXWC3ySIuHphz@iBwmCpf4iAcg8DOk0wasgiT3iNw@LGg@vhfxgb@QjmpMfjJkIG@RpIgpaP4tvpB/E5XfBgIw4RdY5vKkilNKXiBIsu8gKRcw/Fhy44/HDOhWyZ2ygI1F2FxfOQZOluJEI6xWkgm@L9whOZlW8E@2IFekt5lm6PwOZyeS0Dm1fIuQltSllLSDP724WNYollPFVGaDFAvfpAZqumB7dBTAsJqKvaDXA6SZFgsxOfCR/Htl/au6/qiBdV5q5Dk9N5OeS6R7nM5Ixbk8WODjTFtmJjvzJc53L@w4mztTV1mQ8OJBT7c8EEnivKXH8kbeeNAM48w7uiuZK3XCdiIhZ6R8mtP7nLKYKKMZXKc3OF3y95rseY1lIu/rZP34a8kOCsh4VtqapLjU64e9V5a811WmIJvZQE0huDj2N7EdD0rpgymnE5DgUM9Pw3anHENZLaoZh8aMvbP92vakkPEqm0aDvRhnBtacMWJQiepcJcJNyGER6qHkRQMEwURGE2rk7qjCU1l4aoDFXIuqWvaCnBng0LT0EC@jX@RX/KMGexI5lS8zP3GBMZ9w49m7OUkgmnQX7flkSs4m6C7CH2WjHllF4rqnaYjzJ4ljQwus6wzYB7uDavBFPU@YE4WaKWborlMkpeMMRcW@D3UhJt5b/8yvWG98kLGHvWAiKrjN8MkLy0o4uI@DaBxhmCcKSxPdDIc9PHUkge@OXKhlzJC1dTxuiSEaK7tn1dCyh/O7@CQd0qGQJ04Q8h0aiMQJ0U23i85k6AE7uMOpFTUu4dizKv0pKzRgzDxbYzfzQNxEfGoKu/2uiQT3HI8epHQ09FuBZ4GMFoH0Y3FTO6G8Y5H06eg3goHEYEnbsqy/3IStX/fe4Hnui2LhWdEg2a08Di54z57HDlZAJJWwVgAxdr343LKMs@EWnw3nEKArDnGhfw@8GdwG/X5gVWDFoIwRCK1RMLoN2p5lnQb6EBjhIivjyST6YQ9uRi1W7oDQ5QMzopdw5PJxGHAY/uL6zMfFLTorcy08tIpPm6Grb8M2ElB5nHQGeDpMBxYYJoDpgYWugzEQZcURSZTo7FniQrLLNSqigBoY58Q4m9Bk6A/GYQt6hjRZVg9A8TFIXFm/ncIE6mv1fHQO9uYhgO4xMQUUAuoo6TEcLHlo/odwELJh6ozdVz2Th9lvQGMFhnswCmH2jQlMvULFDNyhg8/e1uqifnJw9qFyWhXw/O705H1tv7ovdj/SGTcelFMcW/H25BBmF32azqfmJ/DBrtShpE0JVuX4o6j@/O60Wq@Lk1NRO3p3WANoAP60cnxWq9ZdUTveOzzfp9N3gCCOT87EYe2odgbZzk5cqlUVs@Jy4uRAHFVP997Ca2W3dlg7@0g1HtTOjrEyPNWviHeV07Pa3vlh5VS8Oz99d1KvCmyYtV@r7x1WakfVfQ/qhzpF9X31@EzU31YOD1MNPflwXD0VZCRgtHK3ClhWdmELizVRO/drp9W9M2xQ/LQHxAMED11Rf1fdq@FD9ecqNKdy@tGVQOvVv5xDJkgU@5WjyhtonJX9BlWgX/bOT6sYCgkpUT/frZ/Vzs7PquLNyck@0bpePX1f26vWS8I6PKkTwc7rVVfgPXVUNcAAakE6PO@e12tEt9rxGawZ5@/Q3sGBTv4AhAEsK1B0nwiMZhDYWiDSyelHhIp0oA5wxYe3Vfh@ijQlalWQCmhRsXdmZoMKgYhnZjPFcfXNYe1N9XivisknCOZDrV51oMNqdcxQQ4OMj8A6UOk5tRr7CfDiR2BWS3GuS90pageisv@@hpjL3MAB9ZrkFiLb3ltJcw8D4xpKlHCAOgP/2lSsdGY/3QYYZ3JWIzNfR6MjJu2d7FdhRZZxq@w44RxWnc1UKCUzDVYanQiviZA17eDqptsM@50B@pjqYqz4uI66Ll744uC9FxfWI/dqSP0KFchkms33lSZsdOvNpuN@T8kEGt8qIdXgj@VyZBsxfD/uvFHxs7XFdN9OEGrnqTzoJEM9PIDAnEz9p2z65l8Hjsjn24Eshs77CFipjiI@NvmMRykwNZKzI17OEVdJmgl6DyU7UMGsAu@1mqgnRctIyjSI4E//a/zCi4PxAWZnVnfl87iJJTTC3wNVDVdCIRHoj4xIEHaoSi8Kgl@72YJZHe75ve5g0M46jipDecewD@xmnW8Uvwq6qeK5dHlClo6dZdz8SO27SYTR58@SZEL2izeilmXxT3NMP47ChmM@oNaUqiJltVRaZp9ycbRIcoUMbYHuFdTJKPMdVX6ufcDdXGHteSn1/a3@zmML7QUxHi0seA0qd0k/by85AwwwisUBJAllhIx83iij7E105jvI@Bkz3YVttPyBtfpzQOs6kAQE2Ru/Z9aJq/EonJjYwzz85rRytHt@cABTJ2L7fHP9xUbJ0mG3fnb59yPWQ0FjKerYENZxkNMoyRgleyD40EgxwmrH7E8MnM9jRoyprjqNPmKcB223kbRkwokMmxvhTTV9NNGzA6SDLSgAx6Kl@HXuyJQMkE001cHWXPsTEvF9kJWIB6QxS29KvTbBPwhbD381xHWDJANJFqMwusC5sLugec8@UKaitLmhwD2YxbMVH3MYN00DUnWR/Sx619Kb5G2jFyM2ZcTxSt1OJQGJxTQWQtlV9Hlkv6M4I1IBTNHD4MvPkt/g8aMMcEfh7vxoXBnXgYwHuiTqqWNltGx0Q0K@3ClDFz19qmvaFqjldyRSNPakOlkHBjFGA6GCN46gjW8ScEnHEUlXSRawr5cd8YU5FYN3IJyS5Fj5Dpw7rzkSSknFD5HvKiqFYFg6yAlT7U7XYaksH3UcC0XOBJl@iB4E/0@kyRz427DjBOgxtYwggN9FSYLKtILtKxElvFMHDcbpRkxN89PHGMy92TGfdcPk6c2E/WuABLJ3purDRwp72MnOIQAyOSo2zPGrTdI@@7B1em07sjiek/Rb18OskGuFWipm4OY2Ll0Su1x1toIvjnBY12RUeAhFxWveuF3RqIctU2orL55ENoNzVPyP/AopQPSAJy79zFarac4qyFGm5gEZaslYcNo6YhKIpfcPntqtCCNEZmLulydfilAAegfxmW0nXfYxEGyem4y4SCuxOKMoeBgaHLfJuPjIkHVXZIjZCxDOkzYpQ/A@kPEdLhA9hk6h@mJoIvuEDEWwktjqMI4ziNOt4wFpaVm909iTZhI5VGN/3ueY9AFrtVQOjwN8SAxNd3lPHPlTQLn3fc1mFsuv1Acu2i5iZayWkOXx7pPWYDAC0dHHdgOObjh1PPFBKh2CfnQzkvELYT0LR1IjoYR@qAbFJt690zLD4eAJtSgco7dC2yP@oCZdB2ghyuFJJrkNkQXmVTy6o5SO4WS1KLLbcco20ITCkhIRt8WG@PqVczFBZcjQgCgYRnpzQTabVA@eO@jhdzcY/YprP4pA/XbQ1pFJDZCkC@ROqvUpxmNrzE0fDiLSaEBXoAZEU6LIijRtqApr9AvJTtKuyY6jY2LsUmrJH69HM6myloKKYsaVtQPzbeSgM5FKazI0qA4WWlxbJ1TmbbjuH9yMUbTQ5LG1sC/6ekrZYiGi/ESJjvjE86Z@@ohPUslffhLh6IEveMYtRVBEGGVWPFednecIP7Qp@BAGo7apEwVJpu0PUf1GW59Bn3hRqQ5l2L@WP46CKewAWvlwkicYzexPg8/95t6g53fDQejDPg0juk94xsPHKT1ih3VHg7uIrvWhhLaRqT2Nnzm@DIdhw3d9LlkyQnNF42CYNc0UxqNp5TOHiSDNORoBxjdOEn8P0zHSdJnn63EhK@l/SvZ4Raf0YNlnxXmF@UQfAcgJbidlQcE@pGNyTDKcT0szGa4ey2DgeCVywncesNhLYPwSSETHMAmMFTIzZglmI3Bn9iDGjfbEbVMMwhEGWgr2A7x9JsrSZ9fHu31hFnmFlgJborhZMIryKcoE4xDiw/Rhcq@9@JOxBwR@AP3is3ncMo8RaIrrqGhLEe9XZJRRwIXMA0Oao2kmhlks7MIq1EsAbU7SUJPJ04eoQZY/IBTJMHszXIkjMgsbH7wpLtuEKac5dXBRWRbLDsXtQBGkMs4WHmbY4Fv2szT48RCXNWc4Me1JyFkD6YdI1QIq4TWmKfNaE2WOqfztEbO29r29liJgeZ7JmXFdb9ZWkgt5oIS8vuKx1mAEk7Gdop409ViOxoPh8ndS78G5Y25ktnm0bjnONw2BmdnKsFiutIm05Sk@TktWGp8U0yQpRpZmwEO4faVnzeZpIk7KTRxv5eb0G3R4iGax3ZReVHR/t3ns46J4ixa9aqHRQ4pwxyClJf290YSGNx@eQSRM3l41acZo4pTRnPKjASpFJk2l76cQcZ/EPUWPNlAO620D7cz@eZCoaSM5FfJUJSWCXCI9MXA7Om3CvDTsoPEFholjCVdPUlrgnLhTOsor5q4wyDAmMECUioNcrIdiDW7cWSk@otsBOtkmWgsVcSaCpx3TwkEH/dcEo6j8UrkjLR6a01zxssSQJhoS7Coo12OQlL85vDaaE4IyQwoY4nNIoVs0Mzd9/v5W/WhbIB9A4NKULC19Cy42xhGrgA38MZOaE5SB46pkycSISg6EJk0NMBZgl9LtBbxdRekvHDHHo3WDHEawgeDPWfxZlSUwnPdGQVMbi0zaU8ziSHLzaHNEboeLxAzF70h@ORRZ1KWNKwAIGGMoXy4CBAxrStjjoQCF3jE5L4Go7CMoWC7isISPFBU1tvOck45ElRmerxs5CvNyvDRh5OYCAcFifp4YEZBZ5meJocBCNxcXI8eL@e2Jc4BArHifKQ5dIXslSUPdc0xAusG44MQzSqMo3ILkYEp8vu4kEjV/U@rLgpFaSKcCfTSGjVwxnbpZSKQmql1bSxZNlAR6OGatiUQghWMirGeFH/tHrilmyHNtE2psMhJShrTPxhumYZcJ@zbvr5HYJqdsJWMoeKZnuNp@NfmKlURQ9scDsItlOjLA2O0/3FplmaowkXcFUFw65eyS5Q0hSaw2LvXYLNzpqkh7OkCB2tMOOuL92cFBIuzr1VQZGl0Ho/VCoYBMfGUGv1e21ahKCgf5ZO5856bXyw/vfhq9v8rT3B8EdCXAltpBB9AlMCgibzDq8s0QiANkxdw56ciKe/2bTse8ggFPKLHzoNs4p4yGIGgBCrXRy/szUgARSLnA/oINxPb9IvTou/NZ0JRQ1DEUlEaT4FtbnZ4BefBDB@2z9UkVAcOJWVkzwbrllHe@4AqCN5tQZ1H4YudLbJ5svw16vYErPuDFwBgpYOE@XeDgwCxQ4Cx4wkjevTcRxaN1RXAb9gy/Ysxi8jqCUwuTumdCxYXH2PinQbc6GWbtxicblhVo8io2cxXjU7vC7tqODBb/HWCZDwHt78p97Q@zLaJTOjMs9XIEx0@A0bOiO3fvk8jikE5M0uzbuZGo89H1KFgDNN0hWUDFsqfupZY8kF0T176YFDtIwwLDkDhhzJXvK4GuZn/etHg77nS@b1akawC4Y//QjMg3ofzYhEhnADQC5fADemIU7X/JwbA@SAUUYQEHL@uYnXewQBMLWNaTVvm3u2ylUhFLw9VVUanswkMuJyq7FbGPH3Z3xT687@L70/La@nqJ59x95wt83FUf78UuwCAN52rr82gfXiGtjH5jaK2NXbyULy@5paVmeXunFOUblV1064enf/zbf/zj3/8zX5Ev/40vu/TS@KQzeZ6XX2p9WXp6X8L3xv7l8tJVY2l4udwtIZf9k6KGD2rjnB@bj3qjKyvDq4DxlexI1T6bos/IokJd8Hftj36F2WVLZFpRPiO/RnxzFM2xmVZgfA/Qj/IKtvDq0oH0Vh6QyADQKarjoXdaARrgwXoDlARc0A6Uy/PZilLcYzgYnUGfqmRkJB6SWW8D9GmJIymgLy6sWLmwHwV91IDfkszLzbMsH37DcVPyb/7TUdTdHUzEykVWrBTEiitWbJt@ihsv4auzlA/RO5ezwXbAtl1IiY8W0MxQRCEJerR/oLt2UuS2rCW6sgchqTAVlJm94Fy9@yNnGb5wLepaC3h/pmAVCR0yYZHMl6X@PXTLF8hxbydcbUhQaMpdDFVmnKjo/kURyI/YECCu@ZoJsjWAKvGkjzyS8Smvvsi@tug2IQKMZD19c0DjHj/AWrTUlzbPib0UXnNE5vP8FdfGEjtDE9qYwvXHCNCBCm8nC@RJuJxZttjK22glNZO9sM32SeZjW4dpMFa26VzoX4XBBGzNbRJuqS/9WqQhNx@vCDvUxytGVXba9ltYRpHrm944HEp3BaodB9QXXds9jyTsUQLEcDhm/9bsCCNFgYoUleoWvixrKtoDbDqPhL50TYcOdjw@OTKIkP@UhbH9NTW2nTx5iSh2YB4gpLQpX8cPe5GMujIiYnf90RXeDuh36EK1MZ@bkT4Pb0xNYTzoaKQ9gkwm5/F4hqZkhiO/e@27InM8OBv50xosWyD5jFueAy3EEEyIBA4@WfW85imEuUWyS4giuilkOYSXF/Sm8no07ltb@5xgl6qhIMOu4CBIsBNRMvia6KsUHWOu/gOdYKI8M3nr00g5xdLMi5ZGEpJtus3QMJsZOpaqwRw7euDYFqOqR6biBVnoBhfaazr4hZm8hzECZN229AKUrggbL7F@XJ26Qd9PLE7DnqUc/fMlwesijme6ipKtkSx1CWoxvvEOsQI58lMyCgSvTSqckbWQzS5cRPI6t4y5jlCQb22Ln/dFqC@gowvMyDNEnPdDnixTK1R8B4YnamT5DxA6Pb8L@E3v/Cmy4kUm@2ox7zQ@XfQvV7IX/a8XvzuEiZyS1SqbExl5mK1mLDlWYGXMu4lXZZUWqVCDF/1khou@YB8WgwSASD7b@JS//JoHhC4yeL38RYYJkugyxCT/eH15BJ@fQTOTxCKfsRacFUd1fvZV0RGwttIv9iF/cPgXsFCbSlLTwz5n1AFQ5Kf72w27nET5zbXC87Xic9gJdYNJbhTc4Hqbi26uggmIEhFuZ2Hpufg9wQ0JQtxPIr8EHyfQTr7WhH1PIumkJKdQOcypHkuzFZTxmCcgP1CZwqWii4uj8/h4@IgbflcAy6m8FAuKTQcN7svi@hkNrrEeP8J5Le0dwhyJVgZsI0Iq1BxCVpevPMShjhouy@Tn5Ik9jN1KQKB78xljtegP@jkprDnecgmFaPSa6W0WNgvpMTozRBMjdEkKU8uLorjz6sXf/@vkt8w4s7OW/zCC33Hmt8zGZoYf4QHenqm328xOZhuzbdxnpnnYA8Pji7//D5Tf@QngYMp0G/7srCtYG9PMTq5MRb5mdjbgobi2BvX@79/@Bm1Y4h0b3sW61HQFIVZSFNnz@8S7kC5q2Ereli7H0wo5ZiEMtjCEvTm8oGHUZG2zQGq6jLSquA1k5CtljyKXeDLMGpOpEGsylD0FSEZcoIwV5BikMqHoCMN2Q5ltIPPGaIpfnngbEewAfpHmHLpKbbrxJEKToSXeFkEHZrlG2M/zw07hla3NO7ZsZVNSUiIkbu3kXLv5rPR/)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/wznbc)

[Answer 26](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/103172) is for 05AB1E legacy written in Python. This answer is for new 05AB1E
written in Elixir.

05AB1E is separated from 05AB1E legacy with [`P` instruction](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt#L82)
(total product), which puts 1 on the stack if stack is empty in 05AB1E legacy:

```
Pi26q}318q            pure code (try it)
'F*Pi26 ^qx}318q      code in polyglot
```

`}` is hidden inside `[]` for BitChanger. `q` in `aatq` fixes Alphabetti spaghetti.
`F` fixes `P` in AlphaBeta, `'` is for 05AB1E. `*` fixes Beatnik, not a space because of Japt and l33t.
`x` in `qx` and `k]x` fixes Beatnik. `^` is for Pyramid Scheme. `z` is for Z80Golf.

Answer (score 4):

## 320. [Affine Mess](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Affine_Mess), 14640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1 1 v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v   >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9 @,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMn>MnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001 1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X 
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa










































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::geEx Cr Uithary,85"3.c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0/a4on;k: $/op>s}e}equ+4[0]!!tfc;""[ ]5:ore>80C0 4?4在ｕ
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ5L3U7W62SPbtK4G46AJQAKoJVKGrABJoNjskza7Wsr2zHo3skB/jK2vWs/J6IsY7sbOWd@yZCHs/Tjjmk39A@7Gx4diw/oH2nJNZhQIJgN3yOGJjY4tEVT5Pnjx58uTJd8vw@j/7WQQf9tQZzHoDZ8zGpjdmHde6MF2VPZix@4bl5fSMJGGoXbc3GZr22CtLEaYx5o0Nd8wGht2bGD2TRcBVZ3N71xqMTTfJPNNkLXPgXIJ/hjHbvGSHdtvqACQ2ds5N23ptuuCXZeyhOXgzfDNmbWc4NOyOx0auZY/JN8fYUwMs3Un7nBktb@wa7bHl2OCVZ@yZPTCGrY7BKPjINXmkAgNQ7XOKs@hTZOyx43ompOC0Tc9z0LEEjoZrOY92n3x8I7yWZh8bgNRoYE5vJK9p7Lllup2bMXT22enBwU3XDPtUcWx2cBslLct2J2PncHwTfo7t9kzbYLpaUvWbnnkg5tgcFNPF9IIX@B1YLpSmIUqtPC8ZezJsmS4QXxThpTXuqxDh1OEEZ449mDFzCsAAxy4EM8fMwtJiuXQaQ8L/idl27M4cPDiZAAfgmsPReMYUZjuCB8DLcZk3Mtqm0jEH1tAamx02sAA7pyuw8RgUODs3Z5eOCwWvcFYkRLyR2ba6FkYROfAkZLaHZmvSY85kPJoAeh7rWJ7RGkCw1ox1zK4xGYyTrAV@QDxyv@ybtkDJsnuYj@dzF4RgQxXg2G9qQBtrMGCAzjmig0l7bBs9LtEdg7ZMwtLsIKj9ObkAkjHw/NwvJryQDMZ76jo91xgCo3ZMosFnh0@Z13ZcsMEPw/JasA5M2xiz7W0W3X/yMMpqARlVtyUFJK2yK8ZYxPdkF8ZgYnpsaMwgbXsMlYs5VH5@DAmCs@hGtMyimQzT0yybZVmobEWm59IMqkQJDFBr9YwGvzzTiyyrAd/noklMp@saPWtgcig9Z9BFQAXkWD3HdHinsyyjFaNJHqJN6RRYpsjyBVbIsQK8S6ykQ0IINcu0Ug5@efgBlBJgocEvk@WpBayBLAXZYHusawytwYxDH40QfJvlNFYAiICqBpD1IkAo6Qhh8QnDG/eBuH3jAkAqA@scRYYZSA0ssRR8UltbKRJbKB95kl7fHAwwVSAWkClXZAVINQ8Zz0LKQEu9qPuZ7/Up@4RXIQ0/wLEAOS4CidNArTSSqwA/sIMo0kHm6CBgdJAZugbuOpgzCBXC5cEvD@WVz/rQ9Q7RFiQsxNWQmChUNKQBRINCYBkoijzLQhFnsIhzGQZ4AgKFPAO5UtRYMcuKBQbkKqUZkF4DZLD8NZBnGiChITAoVg3KVQNENGAYDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9dLc/YC3PQcZDKXIb7T81B4BfADYumAqw7cogO2ehH8MW4RCFdEtiz4hDAGo76BtIASQGYGVgOC5AAngg3hwawXMpylKHTLHFtt6VqCmsVbwbDU8SUISgGQKMxg2IgCA865JxZIwTgIpUWBNfHMAXARyJG2AWZkW6jxKD18ONZYRVkLTZXpXGBjSiJgIRmPxETLxZYUZFbHdF2GYaHB9ZIkULxJyzNfTbC9nePVBQllgnDtGtYgQICqjjGmtgC@UQ/Smy2i3XWdIdWvIQqMgeOMVoheEE@XCOgT59Kcoz6XXsZoNACZDu4mEGJiDACZS4N0AlIZwqlyhCASxmv3LQBISYFstVyzTbQXWYfYGZDCiyiWmV67l0EoD0JNQ4aNHBCsHsaxJ4NBGZo8s80ytVTHvEihC28@FpsNxMFvUKBNFCBaBrTn1KAiFgGke7pKTdWpX7KeM1zMGhcvh0HW@xY2A4NLYwal1wXJYk6NIWgdDJt2GxrvIXAML0EsCY83Poes49jRcQDl0oUmFjId5ARADogmY2togk7mQBQs8SwhjcKNMGvNgJWJWlmVVDKOyQ1CqdJNQnGHbMiBVxZo3DqTNlIN07Zs4iBoFDxqsWoAlyueKhqgyrmm0eHBUMNAjEI6ErR4JhBdqANtAoRaiml7oPF4KrNQNQSG7zld4DFqpkHdgKjzdNqUd8x54DRV26pElEa@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@L7Zf0HSORo4LNYMLnRlKMl5kIe5yeF8lFjQRceg7L7ao0FJEsZ0fj3m/azSAvhBVMaypoE8aIClAiPFeAMg8h6cYQphqPcES@F2SxOfMBE2obZuokhrujAOB7EGrDAnNmOW6IAYvsG3gTY/fhqjEp9AUGJ0OSlYkB9X7m4mryNF7k5Y1vdnVaKOj@tKTLgyXdbGX4YKuAZUoFu160XiF3ClmyEtOOaNxiqLytwwBKZAKRR7rQscFGoIDEDQnM7sdkxeqmJxk8mTcLcpxMGBErpqxrxqj8U3sXoIbMs3wHOo12SqsB622osBbQTfCBD1SKnoYLqgXUAlByy6VOi2DvQHp4TJlukexUS2kr6Zmg7RMuxOkJQiBuITzq/IkPLdNBiXUqmEOMDjlnBqJBQK@JyUoogwOqZRoP9GBlDzuR@oMd5zYNETAYlwDibOrQEWHBiBGyFigc1hta9wUWsq9e76@slGtArOBEgVisxMPK/f@WIoKkhoCq6SEiETUsXMyxroRi0N@MfA1xwa0JeDUao1djfsu1DiyX0sQCMgq2cjJPmFFOT@xziedmwVtoyMGkrHWga5ktcdyRYLGn9eG6jqqRheoCsp/FKmKzIvxCfQt5iVXLFBZBHNND7XeqkAlVMIxxEDw6lIS8ajCbc7Qe7P2QKgE3ASVnUujFqB/LnrrgSBKCp3Ar7S3aioHgtWBw2FPd08/qYq6yD1TLcsuLzgMnLYxIOdNDC77cR8dPjjePf56cwmMgdUq33RIWdliHpvayVTp2ZNUVtXLm2EYc8APm@thY8TFMLIkvJniTEOq0qwNjcvUJ@fR8ac3SQKaEJKDUgAz/m6oNDwMKF1Sy/D6Nxph1kskIMkgih@WKYfMhxkYEHX0N3x8nk5ev8bCu4nUSLgjZoOJwQH4jqlD24@noucNBcz3anV5i0hxQQu1bBwDnZvCIX18Pkat@SYypEqHWObjo4P94yqB7RveuTkYKBQk5Y1BlzLcjgo8P5h0TGlZGBB/YGqzhDpHHPVpwnUpgdvtBQLPy5atgA8AsIujOkwZDP2seX3Afe9m3shVaQccQHaCcFOvDOtD7Q9FNIQHNnFt7Okua0XJY95YBU5LW6zAd7HZaudyZiFbCjdb7XmanTDQISnFluPrjS54nXsKuqhzLVKo1QL9k0e3EPdIiYSugOJj5g2YSml5Awl7L4rFol5qD3pozsBUn5PEk5kcT6Wi/uCn2vaozxkKvz@1xrF0nH@1OISF1Hd3D/WHfmAxUEcDGNRpwC44tkxuFycb2h7wiO0MnJ7DtiAO1w79BEFtWpnN3Z5j3yohAx0xqxGcvQD5i@M1xgjaGus1dRwpVri7ymc@DNu7BCmt5TNIJKIQgUpRePWlcWEAueb5Pjn8xj40IlounQ7MaXqABKE4RC40tUOu5MAUSEgV@CzNYDCTcau2@x5KaCoBMy0EXRBxd@691JEkpppaGn4pSl91blH8pTO7wVrgwlkLDCGSHT55@ujwyf7j3c/Pxnout2DPpkt5IByk1wJdSO1zumFt3eJVE7OF4CJQN1ysXiAFJtBB8YfEJ54LglvFICpHYAXX8Dmg2Fedvh314jczc4m@yku7zVnoMVY@HlREhI52Z4CdEZdPnWF7jvzTH49HXjmVglren7RU6LSmXradgdFLUTxoGAaDlIZdl8MjHNfwlsUAZLyZyWPwMS1QHWY0cGgMhg50Xmg6DkUDi3HwNFg1sHp96AvjnJ3pxtWAgyk3qQ70EKCvnAryRgKYbEBb8fXLSeas/RVNL3K@1tJ6NiX7wRaqP4Td6JrQdYpBawWkiN@wsrN7Z/fYDKQ0QroJJMLULTFtg23BgIEiSYOl2M/3iUPSAodJUVYQjV5NcBAXpFQql84WtHwuBd0y6KaBzqrgUJsyNMbtvjJ2FICnOF0aNwhxYddrG3ZX3RIGH1nQ@z6CrGbqX5yd2Q1Q0M/uEW44GVafNepaI15ht6NsifDxCnDvQvaQd30H4F0yAmvSl62QZx3jtjjrGFS7Oiw1Ho5Em6OM2ONdUKReOyCvO2a47mGEVNgztbUQNoWB36aWDAgNMKqEL6RUCioUtLTAeinESwGlF9VD4ByQW6EIbD6awfPBp6BDcgQ73cj3lhP1aKwe9RocJPVGQEQaY26jlPZwfHAMrWPA@SiloXBRSLNLM4rD54bHBykhkph49ONDXy2AQIPxwUC0HUy4AhNQLOqeg@QAvsLR0v58lBE7/cBpkCDhhIMPoEHYNGnQAzkDkXlGdnlGeErkspilc9u5tBFay2RFpWWN@Ri/M3FxQs/qhPMGwTM6DwPQKHMhuU4zfy2zzUdZeWTKBXQCDTY0hw4OJYB2RaLApCwYfNYQ@4IeDlRDtUorOHEC8BV2fw@kWNvk40XKEDtRwFL7LDp2U7vKN1KG8hq4eY1uhZnfDU9iU6Gf@gSgkchgFptGScQIKGknzpACPafxFvR84Ku70mg27kOOgcNko@qMTPtmn4/3CGPxCs21RqMg8C07dhXd2NiIlqO1aBJMO2DaRtMOmhJg2iGTQiYMp6KJYiTJhL51ioFujeh13Yc8jTeQB6aoOby2RjGjXi5nGkmjromvjt84FAVQHkIr@AE40Xi1isZ4XK5d4lQN6O@hvO8h75y0XWskSPBVUAi4XdAgQ0SA7j1q865Zwb7peooMqy50Gk1UMWNu9KyePmucXZ11EmfX0STGjleMKvQPQXiNY0O15zqTEShu9WxZAdkWr2fKjUqrGk1Ht2KxojKAhIx4/KNiPGFwWseiJvBU7OwsCiQV1Km3@y7Bmyb1eDwgFODRtaCXMRjEoupVEdJvxRvxRBTixqNJEMvVaBTo0kYieJRpHBHgTHRgTYGUUDGhiQvPKZCApDkprK7fMEf9mRsOEIy6gZaNI@jzCXmoDCTFw1LyNY8fVugWevq@3svDgXKLg3eoL41mXLpLHNOz1MLiEL/dvVC6Q2dspD5TodOkhprL6EY0pSjQEpIPh0TZfmx5WIUN23QmXnikcekAKKYOrqf9CQhLf@VMErjKGklmu@@w6OZ9gM6CaR5sSnDGSuHzXj6ATluFHwpR1EpwsgS0C1pSYoFcxOUmfFRGIyS46PHH5nP50Ss1SK1CcVgaE7J6tuOaCpAEYki0AISWC0k1JlaVHNLI1615CeFLTRp2vC0TJOLBwDGItlxch@aDRsNQfOifQ5RjsyMNQH50QTyqvCxcs5Pakmhy1nH70EJAblAS60FpDYVHyvFGHXU8hahSDBvcsCfv3YHSeck6uq7n27lu2fdDrgBi96GQsFdqQxfX91I08IyLQt7nw0J@H/3J0cN9PnZCjS02rziO1hw6nQnolaLfdGzavSTbB36ybGdoARn8@K/PB8eOM@a9fLCsGpnhnWZrOBkYNOZzc1hmbby203IGNBS0Luo8/MT1jIHBB6F8393PHoOu/@z0pKqWQ4FSxsVwbdo4Drk8WU7Pw/CcI02z@tNDHmdMeTMnY7vlL0hDMSM88ugxEcvRoIx89wK6@1UK51CEexHdh7gUDXRlMYpA1sBRBCxRQFyehqt6hOOVlr5G95V9sCCcRuG44jjH9krTyf1i3O0uOGfI@VxB0TSYO2fJmS9TW@gjhlHK8UC4Zm0hTBhQnsIES9duhhPCK1hi0DcH/gziMSgmOEsGbfsA1Sfom6AmztePmaBIj3AyhCQ0TrGxNuia3q1hC6hTI4WHliIbVE@gDUuh5iJtppgY4q5QTbEdMTXpcenpQNeeRk@2a3zCGrtOLu@1pfjg@2YTQGzXKv5qolXBMKVoNAhGUAk3iEHZpGn7W1kNFmF4NKYuUZSK5KWg1zDV08rZtLDfSHlEhC6Tz86mH6X1z6Hzgeu@Nu@lemYFk1tJLbLzceh2H8QGS0wXSQblMLG7zqCj8EkvKH/Gu0tYEGKpQbDyjAQ@uFiuv@jMwkUsYnEgiMvQerVbcG8UXe12gNAKtwAQ1IYr9uY8efGG1aEFu1C90cAaN9i1Onaafcz8eOLaN9fCcZXSdY2ZJ4mVKlW2e/zxZ/V0g0OQhgZOZBV5aU39pZSgB4PegytWwYTrbcbWmBp2WlhgYX41FZCa0pwHoA8weAIVFiQkcoSovzHfzPPSNaHjGTMRc282TDIzfq12B8Z4bNqct/hs4mpy82kfkUyVkt8RcwhllqaJFlA0LfQDFCvs5PTh/vGxChzqxaL7OCFThmpntPugb6zKtE/JcObL7KNOlH2EceLYC5egSkFnoiniA/NWgLmhOwGpoyjomW4MHOM4l9IGZ5q@oohc4RIEwlVT7THRKAAWM@OQJwJWXor/M5v3nASeZRZlCaIkkDt2rwy0teLqxLZeqR60G6SGQpAo73vSMtnqZozE16YWJ/5xrSHOBUOXibRAyEO9zjZAulFomVXfsi/qaaXUSGyyRqPCZ/ghIur0tOxWLOE0BD35dBgJSIHzoeiVdW8s5PVToJFbjMXx04BnJcG3gKw7ac1u11J5U5fjAbLKa3DgnvJNJJcsNOUo@kubSITQSqjFFU2L66VC2XpGnewbC8QhOz4CQX5wGjLGc8k2qkyLx33MOKDnhotd5zJ76nie1RrQCtbuwOIrwYLGuiwIIyD5lAknV8GKQXTD@gz1DAtjvmyZLwYWlCB/amigJ4U5I4dYnF0hMYmUOlKRvXmDDjLb1BmxgYyrhjl9r/0@LcjHRw4g@0isgg7rHCQ0xPIUFB1nkux33hbnf9GHdwxSFzd0XuVCDsfjOqdlnzs0ixSYmmlVy6GeGcQeng9ux@xaXp9eC0EDHHhYfRV23rDVpdeSADSZIqbpyYGG6YWGDcVppI7pQyP2S1JeXJqykGzL7E7sHs1popkpr@4IqZSKFLjbalmrggIRcLWZ/10SDGQl1jxdzaqaX3twgAeaRZCfvE80z/rNVU1sge7QSI0hlvj@5292gP63S6cP7RWOZwaGJmgKWFJKd2VhiahoodfyguXD7pOBZRBhyHQXyLbhQpaMQWBYDpqm9hUF9I0hTlSIEgfexBfoomvYjGPO5xn97/JElk3V2SC326vC3ljlxZOiSSXoLnaICFznskyKREKWF4I55RM7oY47Cty7kfKXYjFiZl7u/cl4wt@gDt9ZiNYIf@vqpgiZzhktzYQOqdGyzDVF7hrnk46jjM57gVqcXxJ2nnuaWVZAKxGTzE00Ls8@z6Br9aC597@rgs3b19Qlfe7iCs@eeCOlRX37DrdRRRiuScEd8PeqIJbYrRQYVlPNGtDrPTlRQAdGEWssUriCVQkRzbpB5oHRmqEq1P9wLgvWK4DEqbYTiXRmxYT1aLQ6PvZPKX6ptDz2VG1zeiwbeUjxVbIKH5ujDIt1s3eUKjRX1tAYKHonZFwpzJctd7gVNJgppTjmBc4TXSwtuTn1sUFqTwaGOzetYfE5Hv7kxKpxbtFsiLrcdgaWhxV6sEpq@mvu5mnhOmV6hdZVWMso2YGOKLbjSmBaLgWc9hjXoq5gq/eQaXwNKK60DfGJ6qwiVtu5xN9KDaIPnWH@Xt6ovV6K1XvIJ2XQHhjQlK9sERZGHXFU8w5evbQ8k17LCXu@FNFxe7DUfbEW@OOJ4fHBuzjbswaOx07ovY5APReowN/LeTpMS8uwFRplD5vXiCF/8cS8QI1Bzxnki72UAa@VpT5xuyj6xfd9hVwgpDTtDiHla0COrYnvStF@nnLP7yog2v/l4sLZkHFNK7tMUolJndW5g74Bzgguz9lBukgx1RQfQ1yRMM7lXBoz//tztB6rSOu3HqMZadSg4GGEUhEMY5dr2T9Patn1qXXeTyjdAlu4KxOhwj0fmNBe0ftWkTI9rX1gDC2dfn8R1R1MzIm5tK9x1Hpp4lbiNf2M90cqLbKxKaYAcNYB97wEoV6LzuF7YY1NNdrWChMDeu3m3drMolAbgQI@wt7zUzA8RcPtGD17Mloo1YUOmn28nmT9kV@lnc4CdujzoXKoeIeytKCieyb91naaeCcPV55Vs@l0WugwoamcBcu6zlQmiPvS4u@FhMllnvI8LE7fuSHj8jSILOG1jStFkL6qb0@BS6WUbdnmeIbv95SmLccZfEhJgVDtWKiNgXJJa3jXldgtdUfsTmHz0QsPxzxa3VXjFry1Ed1LoA/2m9cVeniu6b1KU8HZ1CHOdC1a14/ghGau7koFt3TjsBBf1TtYrUuKARFNLaqFtbWOa6hOyxwY/DPNZ9fBK6mZtfAWhYaYBcZZYz5XPJ/jj9wQSqMZEMvqQEelbw5Nsq5R9I3Oy4nnf1YGmjr4W@U9Nc12arpvtlcFGFkgF2x8L0xOh5SlsWNDF2uMCwixqzLAJarCdZUE9qcTlxL5cGj0TH5OxTpJOR@zwGU6vGc3Ny4fvSjzpTltiDYfYV7NElCpzs2Z53@XAnw8a0O5ToZ3j7jdqPxtHAZ9j9q@am3s7SbW7jt9u2/2@YL0wLaqcgA/jvm5IutQB6x7fVwjNxotrJ0P03PgDAbvQ08UjVxQOk53KU77uKsWt4R9ENyZ0QIP8blz/M4Yc9mBhpW1pm9OoF3ynLEzMhWyrQo6wLEe/l4lQ/3Z7593EGltVx8o4n9/Xvh39i17hjMejejTHA0mHr0oqkKboe/Sm7p8zQuttnTcnvraGbZU4aiKBTE06b5cxLSscbuPm9A5Z5s9p9XuW3ch3TKNsW2dp/xRH259r74rUsZiykN0VgcWkNedqcgv1bD/CX4OVxW6GEDizVpgWKOvLBuko/3eysg4b3t8QBRNrIxjwqHayHeFl2k7ffnVxBrPgYYWSQUjvHxmAg2rcBfLMlZqVrT5Yi6GxXKNlVxKSjoq5IqZBoVHWzm@tLCALlTFMhn@WoVQOJeEUWjBy4eQWywqogFCKzR0C@4L/LWwGmppI2f3Jz3vtsDkI/YdUNHwtXrYghZJh0atoc0ybPFZRWZ9kMLdk/Btgs41MddOq@TWzqtQOG2gGI4FnyZ8oOgmK8fQBtbI42@mdFfOxolFUtAXvzllyGkzW96ZFgXTMbt8FgRNd6mIQ4fmaUEHUdo4p4@D6CjMueLFBZft9ECoKwM2D@yHXaW2LF1/tLz4gzZT@fyJ2TNwEfcja4yrQJdwBbHssnVLd8L@2sTwrK9NIGermA2PguAzkW74zAC0LYH32OhZ7U8WCiJAUhBYLCHlnwX2R6fbZXHZtzxcQxUY1gxMIctxJkaua0K/YUnIm0P3wSkY8wrE91cuDb1seN0ZzXAb2oxM60bWrTGNsorvqq7jqtVla5G4nAxHE098luNAq7TCo9DDc3L3Li0ArrwC0cr6xmC8fKQ6NOQKWphoFOfGVdr4N6yB02PfKKYZKG2ghKFyvoRxHkDz/BSXBrn2Ek6ktN9z5hMHOhSXZ@wVlK2ZYYplW@P1oznjMS4T8r@YGd5y4NaH1CN8q/c/FIJyupwij@7W9ed7nu9o34HzTpyJ2zbRGBxkEu4WiFTNPX9ZM24VcfAglstwL23t7A00h449GSvuxF7bKuTXtgplNi3mQ2zAYl/bf/wsHuYGWgZ@lxZqQudv4g1mc9PKNQM3mMyyQRFbLUcXQ/t9iYf83KVjWoN8R5xdPByqTeL6obOsv/N05prj9@4wgfCfDB@abZw5vDPtJ85jx3agNRqBoBwem/wwgYW1HssjYrRHuF0e6NO5M5kTAruiEeLahjEyW1C@g7npfdoiDvihMTZWNEU0Nkj9v8B0J69Yg5bpvqRBv5B5VZd2EaFPzCn1LVYzDK@Dyrjd5ioxjsct1JGFGRtv5Dg2f5O0TcNHe7xeqkBTQK/3nytXcYX/wrjA0v7ZYlaPLvhCEbPDT7tYlVfXbDkD/l6zLMm2@LIAw7VML/UID08gt3yWKaB9eWtlSGGtDJl3jUCTvTA8mqdf3tWYg9SmH7AKqG@4bQdnwoRhzQKd0IkHd4jpYNMAXzvQAsJPQWIZ7Yk4e/EutAbD1pBeKzsModI8Nlu43ahFx4SMjentwuQjQ@KMhNCiruBkAV9cYaXOs9hT6I3E7262FvpRi1S1RvQiSb1yupzW6yi2ZbZfGzhq5hC95mPTC/6Q59QTMq4Yqw5VIxpFThm0hX5pTVpcvQYKzcBUxn0X@vyp8brhbf/8liXzIZOhiZPMi7MwK1VXx@tTZp3l8@mBcHVNRZwdCLIkOEeQ64fK7krNE8HD/9GDr6agEW7ms/6ZJiC67p7BB@Qnri0@78OBTx1v3LWmR4A37jtYJU4wWzmIAh9eM9C0tSoTUHr2ZMBHH3qhpVfDDnXHFDrDVlEGJK7HpmLaFwqdMDe9nSOH7yZL7eJhqGOzo4gDFnCmQXnkbywLgonvkgnUsGzE9Z5aihN2ms@KFaDLiHvpSwbQt5yxMvLomxp5Tw8fHZ2qI09b2j7t9nE/xi09buHEBr2YDg1JvTTc0HwnX5HWsbxx6sGJpuw9OlQxwAp68xkNBT44M7fwWTnuKY4eNVLGyl4Q@prj5QriJ6ePHyXmez9ZbK/vOkMzHvbeOzlJ4t6Wr54s9Q7HPoDa0XWmK6Mf7mtafAn7PrNpdnCV9FyS0ipIpyb0RoEZP@EHvtypXLWdkdk5nY3Mz6DxRAnuvWfy@ZWZfGJcWD2shay0klBUUVlJzWfjocXZ0Nk23eC7qjzPrRFKyzZ9UvyzcjkKag6ZlJtZrj2sm/G/qcWwtFiJ8GGRtPRtbh1bCtSMXh9NKcP7hyKmadoqOp8YXShXlltZWIsBls0PD5yL95hKNkXnRQmclDFwlWLduZS8oAxBdKfwhcPzwhGMrZXLYNYBCJzzSyv8pWnPDFuhuax16kUZYuOitrVBvmG@x4RUsMLnAg@EXjrHF6yqZ7E2GeN3JHzqhqLs7T04vCvCsaDl@lAfP3nGnhoenm6yPmAYY/M9MJ5rRi8VHLfCo/VWTqd2XAClr4XXGy2vz2V2Yrgdx55N756Eo82t2LTTYcUBLLRRIHNgTa1lbVWbj2s9Xb7M6K60@T4OZ7agB4dPvRGA3n3nn2taOk1nGuFXS3PrHSXjV3AWQ5Mxw4Pywl6nh4FoaKPeooJDfGlv9JE5xeUofDR4Wad@afuWX9P2FeKrm5N1fsU1ftk16d3yQ0eWUdPaGoC5NX4spwbej5zBZd9R9wzX9N6zTEKorctSaU2WSiE5/bqYxuFQmmIU5tXKPu5jEJ@lfHtqjt3sqO@0rOwdudnt4omW7DEeyL4mJN@@dTyxwwcKe0lxJATfdcn3wXmqf@pzLGYnEvH44sUC4V1/fL8bHjvHt6pB2Ddv2IbYkQYewSY9sQ8OT6cC9djE3aMSgcDtiTG7WtVyJbaDx/uXofGLU4roRGcA@WnV2eaV2F5WLmvXuMVOLstMbP8LjvTkx1ICXDxQD/LElHONbY7BZ9PfnMboYHX2hpFCDS24lkuDTU2FdwtXxK49QGnz6unh0/2T093TZyf1dONajou9qRw324bU/F3LH2U6MuRdkA0qKj@klna3DiA5OvQdFXHPzxeDnN3IWnUha/NMyTsYZ/PKtlMp2qSZUq4BP0XmqZEvtLroxGH7OabyEXtsy3xv44BIKm9y0DKlCWVWZullCY8MYLBNW/jfvHaCfFkmg748YXGuKLBkz3E6IkXPZHc/fooHu4ePnh3vMx/BOdNcWp1xv1rK8WNnsTFTTCinrkXrPaosKqJEoayq1ehBFAgTVaOsTFtj6chX4HMI5lMHN9WK2FsstknwgYLRoFBS//mbqeuoiksX4xA26iMVZYLyGICd4na3P/9xhx@J7h9y4d@v4g5JctNhApLYyrpiIytSlCrmaPUtK3QEOe1ZDc4@n99cI9GJ@MCVl3Q@1Y2zi@J0nAi/MkccLeUnRAziH6OMY2B4TBR04C8s3LDKcejiqU2LrIzT5nRSmcp28QoZ4Hlm0LH8gPrEHvOTUcQ5ChHgIzUQKEm2ScjyQ/zlUMDo9gawcsvsWTbzbOhYmOMyewl8huNMZb5rWlFq0VtRfND87iClPx4OQgFvHfPkpc7GqXe/@t1Ur8LAPE0/ANsvC1sXzL/CzV@ksKxvHwU1Tz@MBB7fJrDmiQc0R3qHbsux@e70ObHwxCpfUjJrCEVzQZTG4DwF/lZAwM7hxOqfQUEBi0EpiV3pPD3TbcTw/LhyKoVshA2TSitxzSlfFnPjHLl8Lp/VUoCkcuEDpIOfe7jljwOMx8vA@NKFNaq@aAF7bW8zGfVUs5qv8NJMbdpfZOQXAaKbEFa67CNydQZxIMo8BvjVRDRoThJaHKOiPIpqURRFHQfaGfLH9gjttiCEzGJALE4jE08SnuK1SWN35p@H2MKriEKXAmwKQIoGrQyZ4rIkNlI/ccbAMgtbyPlGalwWxts0PGjM49eC0TGEyIPq7do03//n3z4g6peK9Z6DyqRvNo/hspWfI4gTBFGWl7Fs/Qt2Nj6zGynOmwzY9IeCZcPMbIP5l1K9FTzL8717@xC62M0j5JBY7P6J7aBCfgCZYTE9pWdSWj4@z1I2uzRLIkciGcgOHo3xBpID0QRiom1aL52Rt7u3f/jVo6cntw5ao5DRm8FAkte2E2eKmqw3AkM0nK3FInlwkDp5/ODAL4g50vmQBAbtReREW5eTeT8bQc7Xbd/M2jIMb@ZuNcbP@ebOm/hm9HWoUaRbeGjpD0iX1k4qB7QD4mbienEZtXK5dSjN4aVCoPf49rVbqMbiV9f1xnbtzI5Eb3PCkorwRUTdwkoApjNvazOFzH47c5ix4Pq@U7x0yAvXxczyuihvZvC8H9xAO3bO5ycdCYeQRyi/fjIgIiU15QddWfuOuNY9P49L59cL8pOBwuehhBDOp9dRPATq1L@pEKXI/DRBcZBeH3q7A6sl@efQ8AP1/HO/grP0@BkysbgkzqTnCcfE3YXT8lSlhRKxOEo7gpVk687m8@HFJajQqK89nUCv@6kz4mcU04TYQ9M3HTsgfh9O@My6yb46GUK4Ln2OTRqcBMmtQGSgZDRAletPICXE0XzTBB5@COnV8YA@kXF12MnFpnG1b047Vg9keyyeBIn2kaY1WHB8H2aajuuzozKV2bwU1lbFj3FTYpjsH3SG43SOgFE3VMvumNNY9DIaLzcgfXSPXj6/iMblZbxEZ0mKwxU7Nw@VDNAvaOsliTEWtdM/sXGZtCiVbksJcLsJmJ@G5F@QUiqpfU@ie66qqIufjN1HYAQ1ItYdGiMWm9j8xCiVkTV2FrOTdMSOUuOHztkskaAuEnzIQ2UUs0sm3n7HDHvGYqkqMAG6enYHP6@tEatrqtoAMyUSZ5t4cdEeaFx4@kpcgl4tRCkT2CqyEHQcACNeSVTO4BAH/SU8FMelc7eWeNM9LjSG4yBNKNesdo@F7p9a1BzlUqksCnRRKpYYcN9tcaimAOwtOefr8kBdcboD0Aw6tKoUmQvy2xIvQulGOCKfiGMhAJ1I6KBI/7QIBrDmxzi2@y7@Yvs21BU84Kb87PSgWYynZBYcL9FzrQ6OMfKzjoNOm7idAqppaiFotML7aB9jNDw3rMnPr8BjrQ6owsg3RGokTIabN7LOeVPT1nK9iChKAUJmsQEQe3CaPjg8IM@f7V3it1zY/@xneOerHNvcyWeag4tENJeuwEur5FiOfbR5piibdU3Lpqv3Nw1j/OpMZkYqu/Xwwux3W4e91JksswzLplJb0YOtp5ae/@LV9DqjFV@dj7R8XX01bcjFavK8MWVPn37@tvk2Lk8vZvJZjLFChLG9ozeylsXOaqRcYCWGv4XnNb7oSsalz61euhyVWeTsDO9ylQtyKlWPNuCfvF7AwwPVa2pN3Wm8fRuvFyBP0xk7i@D9iOzoPnpTP4lGmnQ9fmJZVoqdjbxOB35OnzX4Jb8R/iQSMYUJB6XO3SrDaZfcprtmrzfZN2bc3YpM8HMwFnEff@P58@doeE4Pe30cEbA5RD@NctPIRZie1v/8JxvXyaunze0//9YwZW7g5wg/371@jOYTLffRxsZHDx5ks0mgDTc//cbTr@/u7mYfJnNP67mdrJLe2P6zP93Y0PVtPbXR8DytEa2fn38u6@msrP75j6LNp0@/5nm1zP/xzbc1DV8FeF1gyeCTYRoY8V2En4Y61jl7Dc95l@E/mV93QmYDza3uaxZ5HQEu1yIz@mtGgjLbYFptp/Bfvn/0KjKO1PTUcxe@48irSL4Y4UYwgC3j2y4itcg2BstfR2aparUKxsJ/@bcQv/ZVgIM@s2141XI@rPwsUlOqFOVNpJYHg6brkO7/9c1vhpiHi4kqqXH@c5/V4ZGzBV3eacCzRc@2hId6KelU6gb/acV72j3G7HF/bDr4sfjHNvF0ZaUCve7jeiKRaKgKPGqTIqU0TT8DAcAWWIvGW4hKwspdWNgt4BPhAn7PI8RTwFTEV9wsHIjVuMPzm@GeL3kqz/@xn2Mpkt@4bz6s1UAUZmqZrVqCno2zcpmTP8UKRdlx7stsC8osTa9H8EZ61WSWLupyMpm8j5TUkaaKLugXiZ7J0UjkxZykPmUjbG5jYSd6U0GweZhV4RhbHm4fn7/4X//iB3/xffr7Af3@A55/ZnesbmqLUc25qPGH1WpyzZWvzsgCGU6Xi@Viqnl9FtsCSdU4Zlr64zfRXCZ6gq0EPWdxf4QzEjy1Gr7oX9jIRN8bbsKnFlgoxDzK@nDIaZQuNMFimZhSvwBsavMc3XpK7D6UkqwXSnKjpuf0o5qc1mRebv1NjzlCHER24NmAP/qHJ7Bu4CjyBrlt@D4U6vazsQwDTt71jxSp11MNswGKLAuycX@jvFEs58t6qrkKLoKuLE0N5N2F1m61Wq/bLQOeltE2tLExua8W1KKqbxtTY2aMW5PWtDVuT9qaJkXe1jfYMa8FDZbwn7PEnc8zVW0KIxkc/CmKM41IkX@EpyaxyBU8jbdb9bfA1CLpuqjBiW2lUUsIjOCjNu83Esr1dV39IlGpiP/tWmCs0MNNkJHGtaJsfwGw6rehcqD0VptfbAPYxHZ9u@rs0U9tIvGVxhe1@vZiXBH9/v0ESt/7AKC22WDRrBPNO/dZPJHYVJSN@so8AOAG6C3b21C019vXtev69vX19jb8b9P7WnzB9Xr71j995s@KMHP/Blaos3qqdpY6EwzVALuaqqGLmjoDQw2@EA4aKCkCKstUimyxrciIaYUMmJhZ1rb0TCo3/Si/D6pSvaFg36aq1LV8rqFwGfZCZWWFH6euFfNxFYVU0@k2cQekyl5IkRfvvvyf8Xf27ss/QA0ANLSSFEltYcehxPsP8Hpss8ePH@PvsW3DP/we88dGF3R4bNce2@TLHcjw2A8lnLnLQqVEwcFkvZiXmwltprPItpwvoOj4hVtPNBr9Jy/0UiHKu9m4afCFB46/sOz5J7@w6pEib0ooDNoe49mTIlAiEUWpSZHa9hCXieHItYKdhM@qnyvPdhXs1Rpjmoto8x5b9XC/WirV@KD75lNioa2HW/DW4H9/w/PwikxM5gpfrVf49@g1/r0a499pG/@OX@EfO32Nf8dj/GOPW/j31MO/01f4t9vCv9Mh/j14hX@Px/j3rId/UqQK6v3mTnqQbqe1c@0cDBZLuyzdT/e1jkbtUdpk6Vl6xtJDR@uAyYS/NJisdJeleyxtp20IBr5gGrP0GE1d@PTgrwuAXPizcBnCuZZuM0hogC0V3bVECaTTb0DWx8@kOvRc5RcmaOOqpqbVvNXAQ@rrckMvFZmKZaY26y/Oog08/VQvZVlrZm6cvWARDzT5SiR1dpbiYxJMz1bwPPvr62Zz/8nDZjOFcu7ssXM0/z86Goata/@HR87jI2fowP/R0dFjZtYS9xPKfXiqtcS2@OxEapWds7KCQsGXQ5HU9s5ZLaOgOZ9AFQTdEh/4zCHCt7ZxJkUZKEiXFVLDKpcXlcsKGQIrGJqVIIAIxg3gWBHqG7hUfD3uEp6LS3LEFxovn58FJm5IPb88w@4I9DODf9Bzw9b/Cv/W/7v@Hz9jsXoD1KrY1fV2jJ44/sXjV9dX1@Jdi8diwhLbhj90ADtGubquoZECXYGpHos34tfX3A3esfg2B1jDNLZrFHkeEERAJEiT0uWv2H/dL6YtnjM8J92YLxA4O5um0/FKyz@XGSfHjDc0Txuv0C07m6261vizH9Hp2ztxCpTLViraFuMWPatXKlnfVihWKkXfshmLlW4/tfSOlge9KpuNxysVsOz4YNNgDcAWAaxvyQFU0zPaVO8rkavDIzqXGsRELhLHHHHBEEvT8fV4E0pULsv37sXEDas7u/F79/RS@s2bwGU0AidtwanZ7Fhus4numTdv5KZME/alHNjTxTdvtHQpoUXjjht7glfoQFIxRWMf6TVKteS4QIoCeDMtpc/x6BueMR67sdfWKCnjoipPjtMNF@m0455Ff/q9b33rLFqtyopMrlkNAWAqLLe9nc/WavksmPNFoJW8ecUve@klSlr8ejMlc3oweTMaEV5asRDn0jGK/tBqsp0aVHEPn6vrCJU7y@biMRCvcVDjriP4x521Uom7Z/OxYqIk/qob8RroF/wPe8WZRHarsHW/wehvuvRBkVy5MqvadfXKLOPo4nWlLW4vxD2Y5r17mRLQtJiunEnN5sPd091msyrLMjaK8EJHEu4SXpo0cqN1KvBcqVHH3DXOotFy5T4xh1bMsUi0IsIpUWglWLFERJCsLm6w9jwmaWLMYUPS6YsvSYw6bYBjBFvl@e/po929/dOkvg36kn6wu5fUT549iGhozc3t5J1B@/H@7sOjZxDh6aP93ZP9jw8/23/2FNw9djl/fAks3vNv2LTEfsmeSy/d14ZpGubENJuXk8nlK/bSspoWEHYwsSzL6bnMM5umaY4gmP9U4Ne2POPlS8Md0cPe/fA7737437z73e@9@93vvPvdH/z0yx98B34/ht/3@Pd7/6aUw/dPv/znv/fud34XHP8D/P4Yfj/56Ze/8U3@I/ufwO8/hdz@RPxC4fhPAli//NMvv/@jn375K78Jv38pfr95@/erP1n@@8G3V/8w3vd/b32Y7/1b@P0@h@WH/d7vcDf83gr/Ozzcr/zmu1//d/z/z8QfGn/33a//Cb6E5Z/95p/9p3ff@ve6Xvyzf/3u299/9@1vvfv2d999@5/q737jX2vp8Ov33v3gD//6j37/r//of6D/H9P799/n/91v/rO//F/@8n/7yz8Sv5/A79@B6Sd/@e@BYf/uD3@I/9//w7/74x/i///0r/7uD3/t7375fyTDb3HD//0v/w1//82v/se//e3v/vVPvvm3v/aTv/2tP/zr//1X/s/f@I9/89/@wd/8999Cx9/6yV//8S//1be@81ff/hd/9a0vV7y/s/b95Xu4f/mP4PL@eL4PnPfJ14e6fPlz4fMPocY8FeAT4O5fevcbvwgM/uuMvfvOj3ElMfxW/P9Y1yjMj7nt/wMG/Xae0ScNJvj92rvvfA9J9N8BieA/oNd3A8uCD7d8d24Bsv72kki/9NMv/8WPyBYxyzUaScZ2tKgXE1vQ19gqlURbKgaZIcovLkILAIiUvosSasHvuyjb3v3wm@9@9E/f/fC33v3wl7EVU7Kl5G5S0dYPf0HTp@TeIxwGzL9POAz4OaafoJFZJfE52NjnwvPzzz@Xmm9SuGT9/htw/Zyc@MO4Fy5pF16@H7rjGneG7iGLMKaFcVO4BkkTGphsglSALV8/yWXYNCEwmuLAH37BHQJNt8g4xTe5ovdUwtf8f26cSiyBYfiDt/z4RjKIeCIJbpRykExiOvXpRQoT40rKFnehSStKN1timIPpNDGFnigYIIUEeD1IsGq1msCIVY4PWDlqtSIjVBKJKuQbY/M4yWYRQUwfEBSIWU0cs@ZWdcojJhBezSdHQkKnY1nT5USx@hASrE4fMoSFwAnsixfVWrE6rSG4t5weiWniAeGEwKqJae0t2KsEM4EjVQ/fAirFaiJRK2KCmElePMkmL6QcZY7ynmAJUQbwxXHgnfuMfSRrRZlPoGwgwXhofCfmoXdoRm8H/M8SWyI79O8b6bdFBN@gpEQqjPvvkIq4w7VGDABwFUVVVQY/nCbcYffBe8pBJShZ@CQ4hARxBHFA4ABsiGWRoPJNkAXSj1S3PvhBYJiZzc1NKVKTM/IRzScloLPunpf5LS1veI@ozOR8SUZnk9aZ@7hA/AqlvxnFocEo44DZRwn@u39/i30E2aTv3E1iSiLjZHHQHqFsJxKyDvBrTkL6AvoGEvApAXojqdMqzVclpGSSMbUaQT92dHQkkCCHL6pSAthcz2hoxwmGyWQSgRiqmlSTSfFV6UsOqjCo5Cu@6iYSl4Yyma5nK9B/qTB0YuH@hgYdU3R8@/YtlAot9igfQpeRiXUferZInuDAt@wOBjN/P4KeLUm8v8y0PL8xPUYXKsZZXGIxthWX@LJgjoT/xKJ6sRhFUxyor8a2/GVAeY3YAccWIzVE1H94F66Yi/uee0ds7@jx4/0np6NGg0km3XRpNkeu08YdFmueGMbbffKQ7xrQS3lEI1KvY8qnZR3lj7RfTpN0PHx4fHhSZpwmooRiAaR4hUaPBSlKmhQZjZ5vR8RSCRmvXnHkE3yX5/mP6aUMJlirSJG2if0OYDj8ZxXpsdd74Eyhs56U5aSWxz5YnAZdmfR1p1yuvtWyBQm@ZJ8wPCSM7yiGaohry9XtbSKaVLtSaMwcjVDAealWE2uOmCbVTvZPIcLpEdP0tMqgK3@VLejZXDanZ/L5XEHXsvlSNp8rZtJaOp/O6bpWymZLxVLhWqp9zqYq4qqAeVAdmHZv3N/ElT7yWVoO0WOznk7in57JwBsgJrVcobGxMbhSEMEzYosrXLJ1DdYrBSnwFXiY9BWJfQWc4IE0cB0WE4vgDo8qYiUSnt0R48uRZC0H1TgunQEjcXDSKPxURlB9oDMf@kmRjW98Y8xqNehFK4cHUgTEUZ/5q3EUq6P2VeKjzsQ1ybfHWMf6zMILedSO5Y0GxgzqZlqVItfX112AdHjA9JpOVh6jg@/rNrm0wHw9NaT//3nfhyYWtkc1YMDt1AiMBhiz2ykDjC0w5rZTLTBaYCxtpywwTmoZLb2dmtQkJm3zk64YbqStymNzigfrcTe55pmDroobDaoyJaDL2@LkyJqIV8MdG47RqeJuS1xpH4tfSZ1qx2nTrV9SR205nZnqjWcDXJE/cNxqFLSsqO9h4UWquAetWmcNdeSMoDXUc4VEXUuDTMafVkzqyY7aHpiGu5Mr54poCaZLdnLp8qVld5xL9fPHjz4Zj0fHJi3638mWyh0Vj7PAjec7xXIu16jXZTlRp2QaeIkgr5DKxgYwsWl0FPh2HXvsKXqxAZE7llutRqM7GU1XtHImXZSug@xLQDjMU03CmAnMSxKJdyU4vmw7NtSuctJIWleU73K3273eukrMLZJxpXAbUORaMZKtq8BaUULhymySVKy5J7gYXWhcrsRcUVnWc0W5Uq/M7YW8XGlcS/eHZscycKn/Wfrqdqw8SCEONQIJnTHpuuw6zrjcMruOa84DZrS8H5AjdDtAVr4OkjtLY4pXt5PLYyCgIacccCo/V6xGy9vqIDgb@9Ae1hvb/oljyKG6rugZJaMpWgb/7zDo@P/@4XX41/ENsTK6dIq7bp@A/IQGwmaPcA/i2GGnjkN32T0w2ytC7PUNWse35zqe9w8I88Cwz7nXQ4sfdRV4fWLgJRbe0Br3V4R4NhriJknT/UeDsD9sAYJUsSnAA3i5A8dZFqDAnj1dkcvHweGSQAx@uiQEPz78@JPT0Pd0f3fvEynPHhw9eXjjkxOBcuzR/sFpYC1wXz9qLgDx9f1Hj25axSd79Oy4O3Fc/EkHR8@y81fghFvDpCw8i4ECZwIiXmiF5rlC480bLFfwDZqEi4vvQS/snjDm8nNjGo3P@b43ywsWu/INjmXp1N8MZzAUQC2TtfleWOwW0pkpQmnUCiVJGjHbuWSFNOs4g4GBd4N2N8Cxb@AmHxPVoAFdYYtJXzruoHNpdcwN6THuJyppeAEiIiF9AkCGkzYdUGCNJTyBq4O3duKsRWswMdkEb8Zd4QgfdEKja/X60MBcOn4AqWUYjNazfNgD8c3wM17vMOZpkNstn8Ht4FJEMsZGpFi5d0976kJNqaXL5Z65PwUuZc@g1hjuLFnMyRm1LR8wtRlhPavuNUZQVJlsXkOlCLTYjbN0ysg6duW8zDZTzqjmXZvX0CYlstDkbGyMu@2KLENjlysDuWvF9F6aZXeyf/PbP/77P/01kHZbKXhFNFnGZc0bmqSSuqyXirliKaMXk8VSMZvT8rlcUtOT0BsplEBhTGtFLV/MlbRkMVvKAAuWwDdXKkgRvmYstUUg4VsGsHYb7@jbJo1b7dekCJ@4Yq9jRpxFjMA@YbIJcWS8ld0b077JLasq61mmpRl0tgCiwdoscnCwlz44kOUHaMEJ@720LHfQkium04UHsmySz14RNQjZ4XGKeNSJPOaWdPrBnixPOAA8JVSW@2jZz@MYjixbaNnbPTjAdLpo0TE@BDvnPtwy8C0FCGajJZOhBQSy/CoAB@F2eUJZwnQfLZgm@hxwnz3wk@WPfXzSaYBwzMNxCJ/4ed3dleVDbtndRZ89yniOo/opWnbpkWUXLFAfZLkHhp4LNVGWW2DEWiHLbTC1Zwa44Y2IeJSkPTZkecYJhCSS5SmFNtrnstz03TGZTz75xOiPO2aPPzOXf9uAGvhY08n@Qevjj1u9Xsud7e5/fIw@e3ufGN3ZxG31WiJaqwmPA3HA53w4u/kAjofNpjFY6vMp@Ng3fJqzpom4NY1XgJN4epjIsLkHPnvgs2zOj0ODZwhBW/g8GML3gdEiH/8hH/pOWy25goyKSixdawx1hm4YTg6NtutU0D6tbjAWjUWTs3o@3aiQBxuCupquXNN9xjF8Gzg4EL@a1afVdKM6rRZ0vlikG5PPpnrOkpMbwx2tlCtvGDuank1My7h72ulGWVTRdlhMu7f1msWexHf0TLYsn@3sKHJda@zoWrGcL3yxNZHleBnfO5lCGQKmo9B1xle8XmjsFHKhKIVCwkjp5UIhXrkGcoyhJW5hp70Zi12axnk8juhiFw@ywG9TnlE@rUo3Nk1OqxwvNotXplWtwk85Y@lbsDp4pOakPXZcDrEH4KY76TLd1yxrpaIM6adSsXgcJBMJEfjO15k9/9rp@enp5yCzoPMsup5P@SWgFWH9@JM9FXqjwoZHYaoH2FlwXHUPBcuCDz@p0Xc6BY1a/QSaPuhP@G64o8V1Bur@tG2OsMfhe/gHnKniWCr19JMFOCfQ7@Yp44bgCp0nYbdNhieFWh1mVGtgMjosRlgxI35JjW6zVqs2q0N@5XItiPUpo2M052AOPY57sE2Zol/hLg/h0aymryut6jQyBTjNKlO0F0On80JPtCsdPCD0QfUBRq404duqmFUTL56WI3Klu2NXGZvYntE1n5oubro/PNoEFQC3fsS6zIxvsjO6pnoP9e5rpeYye47Zk8kwZii1VnzRKWRF0sS@5mf5ivYi4Sz6daVbZbEv4pVXYHU3WayjPojvZCud2APWjINL@kX3RZfpLJ@t0M19MYQElYhoQ9c/x6u1T0Fr4YDPy2VARJTxOcDElACs1SEPIz6yrivt6oDFFDZlcSJPttKr1jH2G3xtK7LcUJT6m4ZUU5TnUg3qaWUWMarepEWnSrN0S9PT@coU3LRCttKHgjW@mFbc6mjimpUBWMU4DN9yZVSAnEA1APP6TezdL34zvq3kqtytQqDeDEBRaKrN6rRi4zk1wBLVTBU8EvVsOgn9UXgVktAg6/mklk9mktmkUkBXaI2TuSQ4Qp8EWv7YICYzJifT07SqJTVTS8bSL6zOi3jyPAaKBpGMxZNjZx9vvQYXKCTkSrLC12DxhL41YFAKDjO2FWJTkBQVzBjQvM9GVrKPoI5NY0Ax4nGFZbZig80Yhtk8nYz2641yeX86@hp4xZRXO/lEIZ14HY9XYhvxqme@kmoVqYZShXI92gCeFUNUzJsM61DG402toJfr9RbmsJBOZtIZyJzVfNPblmtyI5neyGtQQteM9BjGBQbXZebayNytiZoyXiHPtJJekVRabkEpajG9pK8YloxLuNBPAJRGQtghfVnsTPY3Hcai0YIejcajFRy23pDFGCRIOH4bPYja6D1tRwb9SS7LJR0DzAUl7StLh1Woawl79yxbkiJX0vXV9TZ0T1O07g6VwQ0yKWrtvhQpMwZ63Jk4uSS1wdiHLudLbNe@4N8zXE0McCU6Zw40R1pjY1rYp2Kf4R7aHRYFxAx3WNf1TKOuF6B9A5npB9V1rYJD9RFctqzWgPLeFeC3najh9pNP2WxmJBSfsvcY6yU2Jcp05CbZd6u7vePdim/bw9HCM0mW5UpUjlxFI9Fr@JMi92nPi873vLBIaNcLDkfjSC7Q522EJAbbu/KHjsp420nMKHP5UG/E3z6xBlfFjMLHB0BgXV9HNlNUImLrQOXTF3oOysh2/L0E0KfBcRhounI5HOqMpF6MvG/oxczjwyP7oXtgip0ExWxTrkVYWlNwZX6lLFxzfJWwXCrqsn6ejLD7kUqEnStRrUy7DUYnpS8KXxS/ePzs6NnRgRQ523iz4eAoOPOpwt7aX/0a9AWimWyUsbNqZFrNVsSiqlpN0bZ1PBKowMog67taXkm/qXHurZFHXgefd7/4m9npdhHsOiivZSjBXEKv1bQtncUjo3df/gGeBXG1/9nuIxb1jBn7@z/9kV74@z/9V7RYKXpd8WjItRCBkGjU8oXI1dXo6uoaHu6XizQiHKlsIQ5mPryvReZ7HMopw9gqJLL6fbuSEmG1ghaPeEpETGIUchHvjfDS00Xw8mcZyEnOYwlE9o@tnK7d30ae0IJ9UCz42za9EjBF8fGLN4yBpV3r9HqWTqZUipXfKmz7rbLN3uIo/Vtlg72o1nBmWMPdU/649BZuEsHJn2gtkdqKMj0HfvXrSiPBaGQb@ndfmOaWfXaDo882cA36otOWDX/mlkd/GMl38MDq28ytl54c24qnUp2OODlo22S5GrDCVgowO4u/@8Xf0PX83//pr75pvml@rkMfrlTKa3rkZ9rPfgYB1uzg9ztgNICPW@3REHTc2IqLsKFXKkXwdvQu4@H9bhx23FB7sHo29MbRJl2gxkOl1OTHQnViFGwLN/gmSX@mQ1viFUkK9EzSj91eO0kw2BZeUgC1VLqSvoJe0KyyKghO6StzUOAwhIbUaTe9wcQd0baAGMXTGkl2D6JACl/BE7c2aGOykL4KCKzU1u2oHGWPqEbaERuanofnd0F7In0FoogD5fDuZQP30GNIywZxr2IQwpM8OnVIuwFpD3iEJrnGKPc8QJJx7HgkG3Ro6SugFhAVLNAWmLUNASogYr4CBIA8xARgq8G2WSbOrqxEojI/HOwaV0HjQWaGv39XwmgIrYP7xf3IFQwHTqC74xVGyBeihEFRCzn6QDgMPl1bBe0fo5MN1S/aYP/eoAAWHWYTo6yxe/fmWFWrVifOKEcI/9wa4ZgTlYO9HFcA5vecPuqU5STDY9cqvmvAdkDxBKELXKfw89YqoahMRuu1JMH/ezMtcuSNoiKPCmZAlBevFW0gGURGsvMybLPtKtP0QpwFyLcB9zYhRUd9Bd3Bs@lHqv6573kNGP4s4h8QDoLoNDyOJ/j25gZuBg3gBE9nxmN8uDAQG6/5QT0o0A7HfuwgFmTFGlDoruVCV4Umkf1Tv2IZLY7R5qekER60rlnPMlxenIvjh2JhaAZfA8@3Euls0BkdbQcK1Bs5Nh2IRYd34Npt4AiQUeJcIY72xL7E0/xF2VDkMEYenSmEnI8Y0wFfdA0ixcVZ2ZYL/VmfNklm9lTWHnaYXmIxYjQ6/8gOwMUpEiHcAr0XadwamENA6cQ0aWeNV06leqAfTVp0CNRjC/iqf2BBq2J7KXHjZOrSOrdSp3gaseJ0cQMO31IfQZUKqx@fABYHLg0c55wNrHOTD8/GFg4k8Bho/qC@JoGy8x8QtoyLEfRMkqXBO8lDwa8AnwI3FpOhuBuxWfz2N6NtxJpYom@okbFcvE3ywrBD9KXnjSQ6u97M8480oYM5wK4GItcUhxlUo7hNOTilQxKHs1TpXBAVh/1HMeh6@oeaoBG0cvOCYbdVwjYGhGbbPx4AazHk9ivUAFDdg5qF55uN3TIeagGYuJ1YG6qeEPA2@4hldAkD8hNnxOkwAAOLvroIHfwgKubDG3egYFS@4QzkCtTOYQf8cDu1YD@M73M3munsuTl7sw0BDhsdSqvKeLXwLbmQBWsH8jNlfQM884DhEkw2YnICwCbkuMxBB/FvRufcLpEsKbPbkJIMIQhSAxRSFfzrZlno2H0JPB4YHj8PU5yEdnl5qdKRfBPXUk0Pj6L38A7d1KhngXbspMbmcCQu/bLwskcBd25S@A0UeLPyzpTuNC7dm/GvJHW9qliuEYt2vSg2jhd40npvSEf54Bk6HjHUgUW3NLRjYoUJ5z@9kbzy@a@M/KcUo9cIhDEEM03Oku0kAEu22ufJ7mWnIjwuqEICcChF03fEYzBd3zL0fJM16gYhnDHtk/DtrcE5TWECJJkPos6T5jn0Q858q7CPrClEss1Ltuu6xixG/nEMjQwcm5Haw2bQ7JMPGKGZYVf8TEZrWp81FqJPg@jQqPmdH@biOT3S1Xqg/IBO9J9y/yn4T7n/dJ6on2x92uAqGTpdY3aQ6/F4Nz8kgpn5Ya75YZZzH4IMOjbTOAgMOVtwu4Zfu0qxfXpzG5Rj1WcM4IkRENyMpepfnNXPGrZnXm41EqkeMLtMhIASB9D1BtH0shOYkfqDi8HI8RacbDzVD1olgTc6tfuCGzivYB6DAiLG4PSy8CC23lBM/XOFQGQYIKAeBp6oGuyOY1a8EhwIS57AOHV5TmOOWF0g0yDtS3gJN1CXOOk5YcOAGiFA6B5kCdAEH@bXHH7xiC8dnrt4v7ofVqG7EoZ4IFC0EQVK3qgqXNZUqJBCWCmKjyaQHdXV6s2s@P5QFPUbXqFsXovyD6O/8cHod6FeLMeeGJY3GBUpXFVw/RqoEKK6EFVZrRoqV8AgtWUMTBdarn2un4rWGpLZSvndDJ4OZsG7xNtUY6HCb8d5@dDeNdmWywErzKpVyOKsyqslrxc@STnBg2ieiDbzGUHE5wIEYKSXRjNFtGk42rRa5YKDTVdEuwwhOSUkpzwKDz1dgWRDRIPeU3ANNxZPA7RTXC0nAzyNN6OgBo1khleq4kz0SzysDOcrRZpzmUNcIHgIVWzks3Zjaer1ENIhoXUDADLiLQAdfodZWbop8DQlsAUyipPSl1HcJtiAywpgMBLBFX6gZyxgMuoDg8IvJ6gdgLorJ@qSrNEIL/6l@U9O@o7@T7vtmF4MqS06ppM3/v5RHBtI2VAFDWkfWjqLAhl7Ms/E5fMLOkcEr/vsO6DVtS4dFluibIN7yr@3PtUaOK3U0MAVJXizUXCbfdzvP@DsCLs/csbG2Mlmy7zTZBHbLUuf9xmsnu3ggeihg3xB1@s4pmdHx1CobadnW56ZZHje2rkpuh2mODdcCuvJwuh4kiRGI3k3FkFzvkJVt9nEuxabzRiuh4uXg4W2tDwO2TMalbD/C6ZQfBBPAujRKOa0XprtcfxumHjmtIh2arXPY0cj4RmFRHYZyLA26P/g2wcNhnnOvOdIp9@iKt0ax@imhL4zdHqg9U08VcLYN8AfzmEjQsZoRLgkmYFd2nLo5HGqJbF20oiLqJ9@cFT2qR4z4kF8fRHAAjGSzL1JY6SsuyS55srkeDQ/vZMPx/ckjO/JenypF34TZ941r3LPD0s6E5tDgIBzNDJ3o4FZB7nVuYXOAiqBM@pVPMJ7o9ihFVsdxHQXgu6K4GoX@CMZ2DywBYh/tor@6wvQj77/vsVn4AW0JzOQN0NcSBijewM8f5ozBsEP43EpsiS5gLUfvmdaEBavDzpAFQLUWBJcNh7cCRVzBN1uLzhO3gd8B8/jIqlbfE8rp6rccwlO7kWSneuri@hhs2MOjJnZiYmQyRBcP8fH0GEjefV@GUdBR0LP4X29GLRd8cAXmnEkOg9UXsEyRvIiHl/NVjyIFXAPjZQThoer6Yf@t0QzDvFV@Wg19AOi0QgOx15YOPw5mo1m/GzoAb96RMhR3v7wksT9@XcTBOggDsBJzpONrxOfx7EgS@/RIgRh1cUs49GtPkQ8P@Z2GX4Yie7OKRRuKFLVL2Vp8Z6D5SVurSvxEFf4PMmnkN6PJe9iuvfmuRCrcWBzEbb3YU3ILci4MqPdjoUhcpe1JebYt2QCutE4nb2iVWkuEahBTJJ0Y4u626RfxCXsGR/CFwecPoMvAuyZ4yZnKD9vOKYl7mFh5DM0RiGtRbiAkg5QQlTkJBdohEJJvhmCX10HabZXptm@lWZ7Ic2gBiwmGQoktReSFKWAxbOuCAZmd7xCOqMX9p3hs05sw2M7houjFVdRK1q2kix6ES2DQI6a0fJ@DIRytBMtPySDFy2fkOE8Wv4UDPO6FX0TLfvVAgO4YCXDfXQXIhzt7Wh5Lxa/lsbGuen56arRclCmEGaHW4kiQArMN2iNOMVmOyKbY9eEho2UyiRDjvGS2H2icZgk/dLwz28uoRsQ0BPHOLcoMEswbaHRCLUYPB1oNvwTtpfU5LJozfePDmhlUxAEk0lAHy8ch8CDGh6JLgojjhj60owGfAFBlJvl5RixUEv2nuiI1IFDqZAX0yfqqaQPdGLkX4fAjXkidF2NiO@X1yIIXoDvhydGXoXnLXT85AgjnJONL0ELifoiuiZTWNaLuIjSD5cQjXUvBsIbnP0gvJQIbEimgw5Hk3OY2MgZLTIJ@eK6dyschwbleKVE7r0RjaSCqJkrvMlZ5AwFQ7jyx9dlJxQPUVsQQehZTzd4LQvaBZLF6DWXdSFNlVc@QCEkc6CGm@1zugrooTBSOC5uktRWrGqG/Lg8SZJci2ISIqt40NDEGPPUg87rPh4/9GHdVz/mFMdaYgggFDNIhctX5wP0d4fr775C7RPhRgLLFOvlTelt9XptK3sD88E82dsFiJ5J9jC@VDkKUpiTHHoHIc18Ha/dUvFxyQdX8nmiAfQb2r5PtqBPcAfdbvYtOCzUEtyLRcdzHRzP9dWEuq2RDC5UX2lRMSUBh2c8wHSetfW48owvK2L0ofFtY/DBBewuFnC48BAeZcC9QXJey92JTatc5nUbxDZ3QZGqlRkX5DRdGhTz3BHEPU3dBtO24HDUPH549OTR16HRLRQKcdFGz@b4Ya3FsdagHeeQaZl00B4s6bboSbzdAye7cTiebkvfOLPlW7KEC2tQBgxIxWc/UcfjQpaF5PmNugvxeNgQRQWs83k1MBakEqo6BjbZlqDrGAhijmNbhgDiq7dA7yT11uJ0j0WziTdkN5vUfDWbuHip2RStGBaNPyMe/1lkIzXxXLqhk1/CcilJdIQAe3jEnn@ye8pOP9lnB8/2PmVfP3rGnu8@OcWt4E@fPXh0uMfgt//kZJ9JCwsl8cIq7FACXR@abRPvFcRT2rKMIO85oxmXO7G9OHc/MYbsE6dt4jTVtmcM7/e5RbXNcY3H2ofu6AzHMC26lGxojXG9Bd2oBd1YVG46tFcPV/UzCNuCPu0Q@7xDp2N1LQgrYd93ZJmev72LDSwoQZC3/l7dJFeS8PIsWjpE19zhCqxLiG5AeJy7ATAGX39Fl5BbHo9gdlQmCBc8H0zB0/3jxycMDxvYO3ry8PD08OjJCTs4Ogbr068fPvkY6Hl4cnp8@OAZelHAx0cPDw8O93bJgSOQVhlu93858cZrUVAxOFGlfY4z33TXfGBbHPVGDZ5dGrRr0WPRiY3SxzIG1muzE61IEw/VF9wpSVMFLLa5e/zxZ9DmM/MVznD6U8G0/kB@5tElbptptk2pQWWpQX2riOoKzZ6ixWk@YjhjeKeDWaGd/TEyJ5kPnBbxdCyTyXu4RgXHvvkBAFSXfdCQ0AbARlD@gpUqo7tYotHkNoGsQWrtgYNnNPLU@CJCYcGo9/2lJhWJKCbWyiBQ3LlwaON4kFYJHIDvwUEXyY5dHoBlAgcegGW5A6qih7h2hOVEiMn4aILimeW5w8vh6ICmhVkhcHhgUC@2KHDi5UZFarDgLis8DmFAN@7wUR66CdDw2pZFUTwKj7fRDAa8Ypj8HjSQiXwqkda2QUgZhE0XpxrEsjd@YSj6AjfgOiGjO/ZYrBpX2SkuDjJti9911BsYNl8CNV@6Q7zHiniyTVWsuLWCO4JoL8jIIQbE@8kW8QjiPRRaofm@8SDmg1spGmKNJN3T5y9BuwuBB7cQ@HnAACBloafTppaKNpIiGKcrWDnmOcCROG77Nhwe2LkzaZsLEcSqrdhL6/XruCBycqGf5K9TJOygiF6bLqiVNJXZdVyo4yRW6VYVlILtvjMaW7wMY4s5oBknauYgNDZskNqLam0hNaTDzRRtxw4l2gIuXpFqC5jyfVIljudz54H4ml@xCZwPjTBfd4foGC28a30@d5bESaRLE4dfQBGmuXIc/JyNCROuf0pz2fGW4S19xWrt4YMz5e2LJF7Vx8UCvx3TX3SIP2BMTAuqB83z0YJFF/UuUdP8K5a8SQtjizV4QlpiLfeBQT@wb0G/7n6zEvjx5ca33XG3zE13cnzzpspjKSiZxIWpXj82l25JVveTTFKcBhNLQEKyE5AFWR/zXZIEM5DX93GHDJbC/1Pc0261sSP5m34K0SahG9ptmwRCMCbXgEk8SyCDIbk5hvgau@30XGP7ug3YN2HO7P7YF9j9v4@wrzLvML/2KWbrQ1Kr24aQzZ5zc05wd0sqlUolqVSqKhWBIn2cR3DfnrrASE4hqnWX1x2YWeQ9krK7NXxX7JBFRXytLvq4mP2R@@TsllZ33FxsUCIMcjpqivYU5ILrGmYptF7NgNt/GBzM348Ht/kgdrw8fBe0/QehfRdu2dX7YfGyZMB6PNi/PgCWF7f/E1hou3c/YF4kZ6FpTtfM6S1ltDXtwzX@MtN3NPYADK69qEHRQI3arvt0RK0iIjtcwDXBxAJR7XS/cnIibN6fQFmY93DL0JbTIMJeFO9ia9uwT5Odr4UmvVnWwpP6krBoU/8eGsxziXfPVCFlEE/SQ08W8QXSnXDCs55cWUiEIOt7mhAV5ZLYfVFzUFSXgO9gDwjIxp1mNNCa28wMLz5hZBqBS7p5LBubNvxkYc1rN97OOJqagEyboGYXPUvm998Hlo@3VD0sYGE0HmxwGyRpWG9gn1CDioeQ0feTPfhAt6guRSN7FrAzinZo@JVPStg/zlDESCyEsyxsTOtSOJaosXy8pMQcMkjEZaCJlp4ykS2aIUFN8fRl2@xQN170nOQSBEIm3tf3k8kVUPzirqhvkHfidbKkBXJzrC0RNnWF5QVqZyXs4v2ZnqAt9EZ6ekhXBbPtg1Vl/3@q4lUiUZOi@dzGqESAvLG@/uxbsNOtUMWzPwqb15D0/Dm@GsL@PgYZTSNS7wPnVo88lR4zwAOkY9N6NWBSBUHUmbOmJNpOi5GJH@DCeiFABiOR4xWI6VpdMUnhNh86r0gmdMoy0wZjCOuG8qiZof7dw9XhhPzN@ha/vz4ebJgJTQfv0Cr/7WAUBbFXnhFPxfiEnqzJb8Fo1Kds7M90hVAccmN60NmOvO3Y4JVbhYl03ma2pCO9k9js1lO6BqqE1Is@3nqK2r1iWr2XLRTNph5UDytihQIIdhK6SHtku8bcsxj2H0KA5mDSS@DyQT58T6It@A84eAokkIm8@RyijftN3IgiIDXX6X4YaRYq59ZCuvc7UavZx@Aenv0kErb3FAqSFrZyfODO06zni4nygFw07DtQyrOzvk1F4RsqdBFSEgT3Jn43Fiz01FCWkg/cVd/MFTbzGy8tal3fG3tX9ZcX3kqrZAtYfJv9q@h6dNv@tTv4fNMRPTH8y@WkNf39NyHWn4tneH3dU44SW9go5Sjy5gv4uyle5olzJYKvKOLtuS2Ez/fjCbEs4n14cVHw3XC0ad5CD4kUl4qVK8WF6GI3Ll3VNy5K/VK@eFXvXxTRyW@8WhqvFlYd/PAUVlGYY/hkvj6@wDXV1LoG/RuB16bS9XbSNUSQawh8edschYPD8tHrhDYOBQBUgUlbb1Ko842nC2jNhr4nfj@4daSazBPIsRYKSNYCeQUV0Lud9MmojmmHgBn0igfSbDShv1PXWsj718PxgFJUnEBkLfE1/GotKDemPGkUIEs9VNEE6aL3aBLncfBgiL9O2Yo6W2BxrYC@k64Boo4laTq0z20bfQoRUenLVb@wIj9otj4jEnjF71cqJra36cJfYLXIJy0emnI0R@Qwkb/ARzwAgZ8hnTZgFSS5R@T2YUHz8b2AD/yFdFRj8pMhA3mLJEVMQfNv8YX8m6j8NhCACb/AMpcvVZxS8gJBkn0HSbmA0caSG388ZkC3Su6UBWwswub6SjFwshQnGmG1kkzwfeEWycm0gn@yBdkCvc00Q@d3OTuRhM6p5VuEtKQupaQd/OnFxRyjWFYVU5kNUix8kxqo6YLt0dsAhtVU7AW9HiDNtFiIyYGP5N8r61/V9Ud1rPNCI8/p2Zn0bCLd53RGKs7lwwIfZ9oyM9mZL3G@O2HH2byZukqChBcferrlg0gS5y0@lDfyx4NGGGfe0V3JXKkTthMJWSPl05ze55TFRBnN4Dq9zumSv9dkz2ssE3l/StaPv5bsoICMZ6WtSYpL/X7Ye2XJ22FlCrKZDdQUgotjfxPb8aCUPphyOgEJDvX8NGx3SjGU1YKacWjM2DvbP9m@FDJeOWk02ItxZmDNGSMGlajOVSLchBwWoR5KXjRAEExkNKFG7o4qPJWFpwZYzLWoqmUvyJkBDk1LD/ES@kV@xT9qsCeRU/ky8xMXGPMJN569m5MEokl30Z5PpuRsgu4i/FE26oFVJK57moY4f5I4MrTAus6AfbA7qAZf1POEOVGomWKG7jpFUjrOUFDse18XYuKd9c/civW6CTL2sBdMRBm3GU3ywrISDu7jIBpHGOWJotJE18NhD08dSeC7JRdqGTNkbR2PW2KIxsruW1W07OH8Hj5Jh3Qo5ItjhHyLBiJxQnTd7aIzGXrADm5xakWNSzj2rXJ/ygoNGDPP1tjNPBDXEZ@awm6/ayLBPcejBykdDZutwLdARotA@rG4qZ1Q3s5I@nT0G8E4YrCkbVnWn6/D1q97r/E890Uh/6xgkOxGHgfn/WfPYwcrIJJKWMuDGLteeG5Zxtlwi8@GswjQE4e40L8H3gxugn4/sMqwYlDGCITWKBjdBG3fsk4CfQiMcJGV8WQS/bAH16MWK3dA6GoCM6KXcOTxcRhwGP7i@szHxS06K/MsPLSKT5uhq2/CNhJQeZx0Bng6TAcWGCaA6YGFroIxEGXFFUmU6OxZ4kKyyxUqooAaGOfEOJvQZOgPxmELeoY0WVYPQPExSFxZv53CBOpr9ZroHOzPQwDdY2IKKATUUdJDOFjy0Py7cBCyYeqMval6Jgez34DGCgz3YBTC7BsTmHqFihm4QwefvqnWRO344PRD@aQi4PndyfH76n5lX@x@pDNuPCinULjizfEhzC76NJ1PzY/hg12uQUmbEqzy0UdR@fndSaVWE8cnovr23WEVoAH4k/LRabVS80T1aO/wbJ9O3wGCODo@FYfVt9VTyHZ67FGtqpgVlxPHB@Jt5WTvDbyWd6uH1dOPVONB9fQIK8NT/bJ4Vz45re6dHZZPxLuzk3fHtYrAhln71dreYbn6trLvQ/1Qp6i8rxyditqb8uFhqqHHH44qJ4KMBIxW7lYAy/IubGGxJmrnfvWksneKDYqf9oB4gOChJ2rvKntVfKj8XIHmlE8@ehJorfLnM8gEiWK//Lb8GhpnOd@gCvTL3tlJBUMhISVqZ7u10@rp2WlFvD4@3ida1yon76t7lVpRWIfHNSLYWa3iCbzBjqoGGEAtSIfn3bNalehWPTqFNePsHdo7uNDJH4AwgGUZiu4TgdEMAlsLRDo@@YhQkQ7UAZ748KYC30@QpkStMlIBLSr2Ts1sUCEQ8dRspjiqvD6svq4c7VUw@RjBfKjWKi50WLWGGapokPERWAcqPaNWYz8BXvwIzGopzvWoO0X1QJT331cRc5kbOKBWldxCZNt7I2nuY1xcQ4kSDlBn0LwyFSud2U83AYaZnNXIzNfR6IhJe8f7FViRZdwqO044g1VnMxVKyUyDlUYnwmsiZE07uLzuNsJ@Z4A@proYKz6uoq6HV8K4eGHGufXAhRxSv0IFMplG4325ARvdWqPheo8pmUDjWyWkGvyhXK5sI94BgDtvVPxsbTHdtxOE2nkqDzrJUA8PIDAnU/8pm741rwJX5HLtQBZD530ErFRHER@bfMajFJgaydkRb/WIqyTNBL2Hkh2ooKPA@60G6knRMpIyDSL40/8av/DiYHyA2ZnVXbkcbmIJjfD3QFXDlVBIBPojIxKEHarSj4Lg166TN6vDPb/fHQzajuuqMpR3DPvAruN@o/hl0E0Vz6bLE7J07CxD70dq300ijD5/liQTsl/8EbXMwT@NMf24ChuO@YBaU6qKlNVSaek85eJokeQJGdoC3Suok1Hme1v@ufoBd3P5tefF1Pc3@juPLbQXxHC0sODVqdwF/by54AwwwCgWB5AklBEycjmjjLI30ZlvIeNnzHQbttHyB9bqzwGt60ASEGSvmz2zTlyNR@HExB7m4dcn5be7ZwcHMHUits83119sFC0ddutnj38/Yj0UM5aijg1hHQc5jZKMUbIHgg@NFCOqdsz@xMC5HGbEEOqq0@gjxnnQdhtJSyacyLC5EV5x00cTPTtAOtiCAnAsWopf545MyQBOoqkutuaqOSERvwmyEvGANGbpTanXJvgHYevhr4a4bpBkIMliFEUXOBd2FzTv2QfKVJQ2NxS4B7P4tuJjDuOmaUCqLrKfRe9aepO8bfRixKaMOF6p26kkILGYxkIou4o@j@x3FGdEKoApehh8@VnyGzx@lAHuKNxdMxqXxzUg44EuiXrqWBktG12XkC92StBFT5/qmrYFavldiRSNPalO1oFBjNFAqOC1JWjjmwRc1HFE0lWSBexPy674wpyKwTsQTlFyrHwHzp3XHAmlqOKHyHcVlUIwLB3khKl2q@uwVJaPOo6FImeCTD9ED4L/B9JkDvxt2HEC9JhaRhDAR1GSoDKtYPtKRAlv1UGDcboRU9P89DEGc2d2zGfdMHl6M2H/GiCB7J2p@vCRwh52nDkEQCZHxYY5frVJ2ucmbJ1@sl1ZHM9J@q2roSPkWqGWihm42Y0Lj8QuT52t4IsrXNY1GRUeQlHxE2/cLmnUw5YptZUXTyKbwbkq/kduhRQgesATl35mq9U0Z@XlKFPzgAy1ZCw4bR0xCcTSu3tP7VaEESIzMffLky9FKAC9g/jMtpPu9hgINs9NRlyklVicUhQ8jAyO22RcfGTIuksyxOwFCOdJm5QheP3H@BYXiB5Dp1B9MTThPCFDEawktjqM4wzidOv6QFpaVm819qSZRA7V2J/1OSR9wFotlcPnAB8SQ9Nd3hdvm1NAufe4ZjOL5VZqAw9tF7EyVkvI8njVSWswGIHo2MR2A45eOHV98UEqHYJ@dD2S8QthPQtHUiOhhH6oBsUm3r3TMsPR4Am1KByjt0LbJ/6gJl0FaCHK4Ukm2Q3hAPMqHt1RSsdwsloQznacsg00obCkRMRtsSG@fuVcTFAZMjQgCoaR3lyQzSbVg@cOevjdDka/4tqPIlC/HbR1ZFIDJOkCuZOqfYrx2Bpz04eDiDQa0BWoAdGUKLAiTRuqwhr9QrKTtGuy4@iYGLuUWvL99WgmVdZSUFHMuLJ2YL6NLHQmUmlNhgbVwUILa@uEyrwN1929mzGKFpo8thb2eV9PKVssRJSeKNERn3je1E8f8Ukq@UtPIhw98AXPuKUIigijzIrnqrPzHOGHNgUfwmDUNnWiIMm0m0NUv9HWZ9AnXlSqQxn2r9UcR8EUdgCtXDjJEYyG86fB535jb9BrdsNB2IR9GgZ0n/CMh49TesQO644GtxHd4kMJbSNTexo/c3wZDsOG7/pcsmiE5orGwdAxzRTGo2n5M4eJIM05GgHGV1USfw/TMdJ0mefrcSEr6X9K9ngFt3hv2WeFeYX5RB8ByAluJ2VBwT6kY3JMMpxPizMZLh/KYOB4KbKi6d5jsZfA@CWQiI5hEhgrZGbMEsxG4M7sXozr7YnXphiEIwy0FOwHePlM5NBnr4m3/8Is8gotBbZEYTNvFOVTlAnGIcSH6f3kXnvxB2MPCPwA@oVn87hlHiPQFNdR0ZYi3q/IKKOAC5kHhjRH00wMs1jYhVWolwDamKShJpOn91GDLH9AKJJh9ma4EkekAxsfvGzOacCU05i6uKgsi2WX4nagCFIeO/n7GTb4lv0sDX48xGXNGU5MexKyYyB9H6laQCW8/zRlXmuizDGVvz1i1tYe22spApbmmZwZ9/w6tpJcyAMl5PUVj7UGI5iM7RT1pKnHcjQeDJcfSb175465kdnm0brlut80BGZmK8FiudIm0pam@DgtWml8UkyTpBhZmgEP4faVnjWbp4k4KTVwvJUa02/Q4T6axXZTelHR/d3msY@L4g1a9KqFRg8pwh2DlBb193oDGt64fwaRMHl71aAZo4FTRmPKjwaoFJk0lR5PIeI@iXuKHm2gHNbbBtqZ/XMvUdNGcirkqUpKBLlEemLgdnTahHlp2EHjCwwTxxKunqS0wDnxpnSUV8heYpBhTGCAKBUH2VgPxRrcuLNSfES3A3ScBloLFXAmgqcd08JBB/3XBKOo/FK5Iy0eGtNs4aLIkCYaEuwqKNdDkJS/ObzWGxOCMkMKGOJzSKFbNDM3fX58q360LZAPIHBpSpaWvnkPG@OKVcAG/phJjQnKwHFVsmRiRCUHQoOmBhgLsEvp9gLerqL0F46Y49G6QQ4j2EDwZwd/VmUJDOe9kdfUxiKT9hSzuJLcPNpckd3hIjFD8TuSXw5FFnVp4woAAsYYypcKAAHDmhL2eChAoXdMzksgKvsICpYKOCzhI0VFje0856QjUWWG5@tGjvy8HC9NGNm5QECwmJ8nRgRklvlZYiiw0M3FxcjxYn574hwgECveZ4pDV8heSdJQ9xwTkK5BzrvxjFIvCC8vOZgSn6@7iUTN35T6Mm@k5tOpQB@NYT1bSKdu5hOpiWrX1pJFEyWBHq5ZayIRSOGaCOtZ4cf@kWuKGfJc24Qam4yElCHts/Gaathlwr7N/0sktskpW8kYCp7pGa62Xw2@YiURlP3hAOximY4MMHb7D7dWWaYqTORdARSXTjm7OLwhJInVxqUem4U7XRVpTwcoUHvaQUe8Pz04SIR9vZwqQ6OrYLSez@eRiS/N4PfKthpVSeEgl8yd61z3ernh7Z9G7y9zNPcHAV0JsKV20AF0CQyKyB@MunwzBOIAWTF3Vjqy4l7/utMxr2DAE0rsPOg2zimjIQhagEJt9PL@lBRABFIusL9gA7F9vwg9@m6bLGhKKOoYCkqjSfCNrU7PgDz4oYP22fqkioDhxKysmWDdcks7X3AFwZtNqLMofLH7JTZPtt8Evd7AEx/wHmCMFLBwly5wcGAWyHMWPGEk797riOLReiK4CXuGXzFmMXkdwamFSd0zoeLCY2z8k6BbmQwdu/7JhmUFmryKzVzF@NSesLu2K4PFPwIs8yGg/ajcV82h0yI6pTPDUi9HcPwEGD0reHP3PoksLunEJM2@nRuJOh9dn4I1QNNdkgVULHvqXmrJPdk1ce3zSaGDNMwzDIkTxlx5XAl0NfvjpsWbcafzuFmRrgHgjv2uGZFvQvmxCZHOAGgEyuEH9MQo2v@ShWF9kAoowgIOXtYxO@9ggQYWsKwnrdJvt065XBZLw9VVUS7vwkM2K8q7ZbGPH3Z3xT687@L709La@nqR59x99wt83FUf78QuwCAN52rr82gfXiGthH5jaK2NXbyUKy15xaVGaXunGOXq5V1064enf/zrv//j3/4jV5Yv/4Uvu/RS/6Qz@b6fW2p9WXp6V8T3@v7F8tJlfWl4sdwtIpf9k6KGD6rjbDM2H/VHl1aGVwHjK9mRqn02RZ@RRYW63@@qOfoVZpctkWlFuYz8GvHNUTTHZlqB8T1AP8pL2MKrSwfSW3lAIgNAp6iOh95pBWiAB@sNUBJwQTtQLs9nK0pxj@FgdAZ9qpKRkXhIZr0J0KcljqSAvriwYmXDfhT0UQN@QzIvN8@ymvAbjhuSf3Of3kbd3cFErJw7YiUvVjyxYtv0U9h4CV/dpVyI3rmcDbYDtu1BSny0gGaGIgpJ0KP9A921kyK3ZS3RlT0ISYWpoMzsBefp3R85y/CFa1HXWsDrMwWrSOiQCYtkviz176BbvkCOOzvhakOCQkPuYqgy40RF9y@KQM2IDQHimq@YIFsDqBJP@sgjGZ9y6ovsa4tuEyLASNaT1wc07vEDrEVLfWnznNhL4TVHZD7PX3FtLLIzNKGNKVx/jAAdqPB2Mk@ehMuZZYutvI1WUjPZC9tsn2Q@tnWYBmNlm86F/ioMJmBrbpNwS33p1yINufl4RdihPl4xqrLTtt/CMopcXffG4VC6K1DtOKC@6NrueCRhjxIghsMx@7dmRxgpClSkqFS38GVZU9EeYNN5JPSlazp0sOvzyZFBhNwnB8b219TYdnPkJaLYgXmAkNKmfJ1m2Itk1JUREbvbHF3i7YDNDl2oNuZzM9Ln4YWpKYwHHY20T5DJ5Dwez9CUzHDU7F41PZE5GpyOmtMqLFsg@YxbvgstxBBMiAQOPln1vOYphLlFskuIIropZDmElxf0pvJ6NO5bW/ucYJeqoSDDruAgSLATUTL4muirFB1jrv6OTjBRnpm89WmknGJp5kVLIwnJNt1maJjNDB1L1WCOHT1wbItR1SNT8YIsdI0L7RUd/MJM3sMYAbJuW3oBSleEjZdYP65O3aDfTCxOw56lHP1zRcHrIo5nuoqSrZEsdQlqIb7xDrECOfJTMgoEr00qnJG14DgL55G8zi1jriMU5Fvb4ueaItQX0NEFZuQZIs76IU@WqRUqvgPDF1Wy/AcInV6zC/hNb5tTZMXzjPNqMefWP533L1ac8/7X899dwkROyWqVzYqMPMxWM5YcK7Ay5rzEq7JKi1SowfN@MsN5X7APi0ECQCTn1D/lLr7mAKHzDN4uf55hgiS6DDHJPVxfDsHnZtDMJLHIZawFd8VVne@8KrgC1lb6xT7kDy7/AhZqU0lqetjnjDoAivx0f7tml5Mot7mWf75WeA47oW4wyY6Ca1xvs9H1ZTABUSLC7SwsPee/J7ghQYi7SdQswscJtJOvNWHfk0g6KckpVA5zqsfSbAVlfOYJyA9UpnCp6OLi6jxNPHzEDb8ngOVUXooFxaaDBvc5uH5GgyuspxnhvJb2DmGORCsDthEhFWoWIavLV@7jUFcNl2Xyc/LFHsZuJSDQvbmMsVr0B/2sFNZcf7mIQjR6zfQ285v59BidGaKJEbokhanlRVHYefXi7/95/FtmnNlZy30Ywe8481tmYzPDj/AAb8/U201mJ7ON2TbuMtMc7IHh8cXf/xvK7/wJ4GDKdBv@7KwrWBvTzE62REW@ZnY24KGwtgb1/s/f/gZtWOIdG97FutTwBCFWVBTZa/aJdyFdVLGVvC1djqcVcsxCGGxhCHtzeEHDqMnaZp7UdBlpVXETyMhXyh5FLvFkmDUmUyHWZCh7CpCMuEAJK8gySGVC0RGG7YYy20DmjdEUvzzxNyLYAfwizTl0ldp040mEJkNLvC2CDnS4RtjP88NO/pWtzTu2bGVTUlQiJG7t5Fy7@az4vw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/6bdya)

Ungolfed code, based on [hello world](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Affine_Mess#Examples):

```
11
   Sliding memory. A single 1 starts at a, and slides to c, 
   where it causes the program to halt.
11

cbbb zc baaa abaca1

11
   Print '320'
11

      ta ua       xa ya      11  '3' = 51 = 00ll00ll  11
      tb ub       xb         11  '2' = 50 = 00ll00l0  11
      tc uc                  11  '0' = 48 = 00ll0000  11
```

Code in polyglot:

```
11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau...axayatbubxbtcuc11
```

Most of the polyglot is hidden inside `11 ... 11` comments which start on line 1. Some instances of `11` are replaced with `1 1`, some with `12-1`, some
are paired with another `11`. 4 or 8 consecutive `1`s need not to be fixed. Nhohnhehr code was changed to get rid of some `11`s.

`v1` cancels another `v1` before comment (see line 1, note: `l` is not a command).

Answer (score 4):

## 325. [Treehugger](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Treehugger), 14663 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//     xxxxxxxxx 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111 1 1\)     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<['4o'6o@<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 nMn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0k:4o $/op>asequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8 4?4920C05r""Hadisptext在ｕR 8
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgEgUAVU4Q0QoCiKvGJfSVRT1NXtBiGoABSAEoEqqAogAVFUdPfs9rpt76ynp@1oP8a33bOeba8nYrwTO@v2jj0TYe/HCcd88g@QHxsbjg33P@g952RWoUACoNQeR2xsbJGoyufJkydPnjz5bhle/2c/i@DDnjiDWW/gjNnY9Mas41rnpquyezN217C8nJ6RJAy16/YmQ9Mee2UpwjTGvLHhjtnAsHsTo2eyCLjqbG7vWoOx6SaZZ5qsZQ6cC/DPMGabF@zQblsdgMTGzplpW29MF/yyjN03B2@Hb8es7QyHht3x2Mi17DH55hh7YoClO2mfMaPljV2jPbYcG7zyjD2zB8aw1TEYBR@5Jo9UYACqfUZxFn2KjD1yXM@EFJy26XkOOpbA0XAt5@Hu40@vhdfS7FMDkBoNzOm15DWNPbdMt3M9hs4@Pzk4uO6aYZ8pjs0ObqKkZdnuZOwcjq/Dz7HdnmkbTFdLqn7dMw/EHJuDYrqYXvACvwPLhdI0RKmV5yVjT4Yt0wXiiyK8sMZ9FSKcOJzgzLEHM2ZOARjg2IVg5phZWFosl05jSPh/arYduzMHD04mwAG45nA0njGF2Y7gAfByXOaNjLapdMyBNbTGZocNLMDO6QpsPAYFzs7M2YXjQsErnBUJEW9ktq2uhVFEDjwJme2@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@yUMQZLOJchgGegEAhz0CuFDVWzLJigQG5SmkGpNcAGSx/DeSZBkhoCAyKVYNy1QARDRhGA6BaJsekEF21DPpD3AzEBRJoWYiTBTOUi5bHH8SDgtcgSQ3S1PXSnL0ANz0HmcxliO/0PBReAfyAWDrgqgO36ICtXgR/jFsEwhWRLQs@IYzBqG8gLaAEkJmB1YAgOcCJYEN4MOuFDGcpCt0yx1abx24RB@eRyfNISoiaxizCN4sUBXTSAAYZHLKgQ2lnsC5IVxJUS96EhkWWL35QhIA4YgbDFhi4d856sUCExkGiLUq7iWcOgAVBCLUNMCPPg7hA0ePDscYqCmpo50znHFtikh8LyXgkY1ouNsMg8Dqm6zIMC621lyRp5E1anvl6go31HK8uiDcTJHPXsAYBAlTvjDE1JPCNepDebBHtrusMqXIOUdoMHGe0Qm6DbLtAQA@cC3OO@lz0GaPRABoEcDeBEBNjAMhcGKRQkL4RTpUjBJEwXrtvAUBKCgSz5Zptor3IOsTOgAhfRLHM9NqdDEK5F2pXMmzkgFT2MI49GQzK0F6abZappTrmeQpdeNuz2OYgDn5rBA2qANEyQBmg1hixCCDd0VVq5078kvWc4WLWuGw6DLLet7ANGVwYMyi9Loglc2oMQWVhqBfY0PIPgWN4CWJJeLzlOmQdx46OAygXLrTPkOkgJwByQDQZW0MTFDoHomCJZwlplIyEWWsGrEzUyqqkz3FMrhFKla4TijtkQw68skDL2Jm0kWqYtmUTB0GL4lFzVwO4XGtV0QD11TWNDg@G6gliFFKwoLk0gehCl2gTIFRxTNsDdclTmYV6JTB8z@kCj1EbD7oKRJ2n06a8Y84Dp6naViWiNPLN8GzALNYejRi4g4IDaB2ki9BIO68s9gY8B32PDdoT152x6QgKwBpCqHHb6XaBad@Yoz6AYMMOa8/aUCshl8g0UschAdQeXctyYNs0IYxtQrb3nnyd9UygNjTpXcCUOH2egdGIskCkMGze3NsGUAqz0B7NiCwAJojRdRwV3TuO6RGPgDoU1HhMzDN7VCOgenXnMmiI6gswJ6gUNrAsCBxRqxA@JigtzQwmJQr/U9OGGtMGZoS6DsWHCu0u60LnIdTSo3ZotNvmaCzYwyEpZtkhjejoADUiclUEMNXrS5t3QZlbwECCoJLPOaHm3zgj4Yo9BVLUDBSxoocCCoFtBjow4wJlMLuRPIQ4v5a6/BLDLGDwUl6Bw4hqAqqHJBsmY5QgKBStdh9F4BiFDKkoUMncyc3sg1s4eXfIlG6QNmKjgbSR1FTghHishqHAb3ATkDoaIKzaggMGXXC4BbThDZdAdgIkB52wq5oyVJCFtwEdOrazBCoQM4CLQRZ9qCyIGZ@i1DAGATNSdfEWygjl9LzzjO0XNJ2jkeNCzeBCZ4aSjBdZiLsc3tGJBU1EHDreiy0qtBRRbOfHY95pGw2gI0VVDGsqKKMGSAoQYrwLATLP4SmGEKZaT7AEfhck8TkzQRNq2ybqs4Y740Age9AqQ0IzZrkuiMFzbBt40@O3ISrxKTQFRqeDkhXJQfX@euIqcvTepGVNr/dT2uiovvKkc8NlXeyiuKBrQCWKRbteNF4hd4oZ8pJTzmicoqj8LUNACqRCkce60OuBhuAABM3Tmd2OyQtVTE4yeTLuFuU4GDAiV83YV43R@Dp2r8ANmWZ4BvWabBXWg1ZbUeCtoBthgh4pFT0MF9QLqISgopdKnZbB3oL0cJky3aPYqFPSV1OzQVqm3QnSEoRAXML5VXkSntsmgxJq1TAHGJxyTo3EAgE/kBIUUQaHVEq0n@hASh73I3WGO05sGl9gMa6BxNlloN9DAxAjZCzQOay2NW4KLeXOHV9f2ahWgdlAiQKx2YmHewb@QIwKkhoCq6SEiETUsfN0jHUjFof8YuArjg1oS8Cp1Rq7HPddqHFkv5IgEJBVspGTfcKKcn5snU061wvaRkcMJGOtA13Jao/ligSNP68N1XVUjS5QFXoOUaQqMi/GJ9A3mJdcsUBlEcw1PdR6qwKVUAnHEAPBq0tJxKMKtzlD783aA6EScBNUdi6NWoD@mejqB4IoKXQCv9LeqKkcCFYHDoc92T15UBV1kXumWpZdXnAYOG1jQM6bGFz24z48vHe8e/z15hIYA6tVvu6QsrLFPDa1k6nSsyeprKqXN8Mw5oDvN9fDxoiLYWRJeDPFmYZUpVkbGpepT86j48@ukwQ0ISQHpQBm/F1TaXgYULqkluH1rzXCrJdIQJJBFD8sUw6ZDzMwIOrob/j4PJm8eYOFdx2pkXBHzAYTgwPwHVOHth9PRc9rCpjv1eryFpHighZq2TiAOjeFQ/r4fIpa83VkSJUOscynRwf7x1UC2ze8M3MwUChIyhuDLmW4HRV4fjDpmNKyMCD@wNRmCXWOOOrThOtSArfbCwSely1bAR8AYBdHdZgyGPpZ8/qA@971vJGr0g44gOwE4bpeGdaH2h@LaAgPbOLa2NNd1oqSx7yxCpyWtliB72Kz1c7lzEK2FG622vM0O2GgQ1KKLcfXG13wOvMUdFHnWqRQqwX6Tx/eQNwjJRK6AoqPmTdgKqXlDSTsvSgWi3qpPeihOQNTfU4ST2ZyPJWK@iOnatujPmco/P7UGsfScf7V4hAWUt/dPdTv@4HFKB8NYFCnAbvg2DK5XZypaHvAI7YzcHoO24I4XDv0EwS1aWU2d3uOfaOEDHTErEZw6gPkL47XGCNoa6w31HGkWOHuKp82MWzvAqS0ls8gkYhCBCpF4dVXxrkB5Jrn@@nhN/ahEdFy6XRgTtMDJAjFIXKhqR1yJQemQEKqwGdpBoNpkBu13fdQQvMQmGkh6IKIu3PvpY4kMdXU0vBLUfqqc4Pir5zZNdYCF85aYAiR7PDxk4eHj/cf7X5xOtZzuQV7Nl3KA@EgvRboQmqf0w1r6xavmpgtBBeBuuFi9QIpMIEOij@ePvFcENwqBlE5Aiu4hk8gxb7q9O2oF7@emQv0VV7Zbc5Cj7Dy8aAiInS0OwPsjLh83g3bc@Sf/ng88sqpFNTy/qSlQqc19artDIxeiuJBwzAYpDTsuhwe4biGtywGIOPNTB6Dj2mB6jCjgUNjMHSg80JzeSgaWIyDp8GqgdXrQ18YJ/xMN64GHEy5SXWghwB95VSQNxLAZAPaiq9fTjJn7a9oepHztZbWsynZD7ZQ/SHsRteErlMMWisgRfyalZ3eOb3DZiClEdJ1IBGmbok5H2wLBgwUSRosxX6@TxySFjhMirKCaPR6goO4IKVSuXS2oOVzKeiWQTcNdFYFh9qUoTFu95WxowA8xenSuEGIC7te27C76pYw@MiC3vcJZDVTf3F6ajdAQT@9Q7jhTFp91qhrjXiF3YyyJcLHK8C9C9lD3vUdgHfJCKxJX7ZCnnWMm@KsY1Dt6rDUeDgSbY4yYo92QZF644C87pjhuocRUmHP1NZC2BQGfpdaMiA0wKgSvpBSKahQ0NIC66UQLwWUXlQPgXNAboUisPloBs8Hn78OyRHsdCPfW07Uo4F@1GtwkNQbARFpjLmNUtrD8cExtI4B56OUhsJFIc0uzCgOnxseH6SESGLW0o8PfbUAAg3GBwPRdjBbC0xAsah7DpID@ApHS/vzUUbs9AOnQYKEEw4@gAZh06RBD@QMROYZ2eUZ4SmRy2KWzmznwkZoLZMVlZY15mP8zsTF2UCrE84bBM/oPAxAo8yF5DpNG7bMNh9l5ZEpF9AJNNjQHDo4lADaFYkCk7Jg8ClH7At6OFAN1Sqt4KwLwFfY3T2QYm2TjxcpQ@xEAUvts@jYTe0q30gZyhvg5jW6FWZ@NzwDToV@4hOARiKDKXAaJREjoKSdOEMK9JzGW9Dznq/uSqPZuA85Bg6TjaozMu3rfT7eI4zFKzRRG42CwLfs2GV0Y2MjWo7Wokkw7YBpG007aEqAaYdMCpkwnIomipEkE/rWKQa6NaJXdR/yNN5AHpii5vDGGsWMermcaSSNuia@On7jUBRAeQit4AfgROPVKhrjcbl2gVM1oL@H8r6HvPO07VojQYKvgkLA7YIGGSICdO9Rm3fNCvZN11NkWHWh02iiihlzo6f19Gnj9PK0kzi9iiYxdrxiVKF/CMJrHBuqPdeZjEBxq2fLCsi2eD1TblRa1Wg6uhWLFZUBJGTE458U4wmD0zoWNYGnYqenUSCpoE693XcJ3jSpx@MBoQCPrgW9jMEgFlUvi5B@K96IJ6IQNx5NgliuRqNAlzYSwaNM44gAZ6IDawqkhIoJTVx4ToEEJM1JYXX9hjnqz9xwgGDUDbRsHEGfz@ZDZSApHpaSb3j8sEK30NP39V4eDpRbHLxDfWk049Jd4piephZWlvjt7rnSHTpjI/W5Cp0mNdRcRjeiKUWBlpB8OCTK9iPLwyps2KYz8cIjjUsHQDF1cD3pT0BY@stuksBV1kgy232HRTfvAnQWTPNgU4IzVgqf9/IBdNoq/FCIolaCkyWgXdB6FAvkIq5V4aMyGiHBRY8/Np/Lj16rQWoVisPSmJDVsx3XVIAkEEOi1SO01kiqMbEk5ZBGvm7MSwhfatKw422ZIBEPBo5BtOXiOjQfNBqG4kP/HKIcmx1pAPKjC@JR5WXhmp3UlkSTs47bhxYCcoOSWA9Kayg8Uo436qjjKUSVYtjghj157w6UzgvW0XU93851y74fcgUQuw@FhL1SG7q4vpeigWdcFPI@Hxby@@iPj@7v87ETamyxecVxtObQ6UxArxT9pmPT7iXZPvCTZTtDC8jgx39zNjh2nDHv5YNl1cgM7zRbw8nAoDGf68Mya@O1nZYzoKGgdVHn4SeuZwwMPgjl@@5@/gh0/WcnT6tqORQoZZwP16aN45DLk@X0PAzPOdI0qz895HHGlDdzMrZb/mo2FDPCI48eE7GWDcrIdy@gu1@lcA5FuBfRfYjr2EBXFqMIZA0cRcASBcS1bbgkSDheaukrdF/ZBwvCaRSOK45zbC81ndzPx93ugnOGnM8UFE2DuXOWnPkat4U@YhilHA@EC94WwoQB5SlMsO7tejghvIIlBn1z4M8gHoNigrNk0LYPUH2Cvglq4nzxmQmK9AgnQ0hC4xQba4Ou6d0YtoA6NVJ4aCmyQfUE2rAUai7SZoqJIe4K1RTbEVOTHpeeDnTtafRku8YnrLHr5PJeW4oPvm82AcR2reIvRVoVDFOKRoNgBJVwgxiUTZq2v5HVYBGGR2PqEkWpSF4Keg1TPa2cTgv7jZRHROgy@fR0@kla/wI6H7hobPNOqmdWMLmV1CI7H4du90FssMR0kWRQDhO76ww6Cp/0gvJnvLuEBSGWGgTL1kjgg4vl@ivWLFzEIlYWgrgMLXa7Afda0dVuBggtjwsAQW24ZG/PkudvWR1asHPVGw2scYNdqWOn2cfMjyeufX0hHVcpXdeYeZJYqVJlu8effl5PNzgEaWjgRFaRl9bUX4cJejDoPbjcFUy43mZsjalhp4UFFuZXUwGpKc15APoAgydQYUFCIkeI@lvz7TwvXRM6njETMfdmwyQz41dqd2CMx6bNeYvPJq4mN5/2EclUKfkdMYdQZmmaaAFF00I/QLHCnp7c3z8@VoFDvVh0HydkylDtjHYf9I1VmfYpGc58mX3SibJPME4ce@ESVCnoTDRFfGDeCjA3dCcgdRQFPdONgWMc51La4EzTVxSRK1yCQLhqqj0mGgXAYmYc8kTAykvxf2bznpPAs8yiLEGUBHLH7pSBtlZcndjWa9WDdoPUUAgS5X1PWmNb3YyR@NrU4sQ/rjXEuWDoMpEWCHmo19kGSDcKLbPqO/ainlZKjcQmazQqfIYfIqJOT2t2xfpPQ9CTT4eRgBQ4H4peWffaKmA/BRq5xVgcPw14VhJ8C8i6k9bsZi2VN3U5HiCrvAEH7ilfR3LJKlWOor@0iUQIrYRaXNG0uF4qlK1n1Mm@trocsuMjEOQHpyFjPJdso8q0eNzHjAN6brjYdS6zJ47nWa0BLX/tDiy@EixorMuCMAKST5lwchWsGEQ3rM9Qz7Aw5mue@UpiQQnyp4YGelKYM3KIxdklEpNIqSMV2du36CCzTZ0RG8i45JjT98rv04J8fOgAsg/FEuqwzkFCQyxPQdFxKsl@521x/hd9eMcgdX5N51XO5XA8rnNa9plDs0iBqZlWtRzqmUHs4dngZsyu5fXptRA0wIGH1Vdh5w1bXXotCUCTKWKanhxomF5o2FCcRuqYPjRivyTlxaUpC8m2zO7E7tGcJpqZ8vqWkEqpSIG7rZa1KigQAVeb@d8lwUBWYs3T1ayq@bUHB3igWQT5yftE86xfX9XEFugOjdQYYonvf/5mB@h/s3T60F7heGZgaIKmgCWldFcWloiKFnotL1g@7D4ZWAYRhky3gWwbLmTJGASG5aBpal9RQN8Y4kSFKHHgTXyBLrqGzTjmfJ7R/y5PZNlUnQ1yu70q7LVVXjwpmlSC7mKHiMB1LsukSCRkeSGYUz6xE@q4o8C9HSl/KRYjZubl3p@MJ/wN6vCthWiN8LeuboqQ6ZzR0kzokBoty1xT5K5xNuk4yuisF6jF@SVh57mnmWUFtBIxydxE4/Ls8wy6Vg@ae/@7Kti8fU1d0Oc2rvDsiTdSWtS373AbVYThmhTcAX@vCmKJrU6BYTXVrAG9PpATBXRgFLHGIoUrWJUQ0axrZB4YrRmqQv2P57JgvQJInGo7kUhnVkxYj0ar42P/lOKXSstjT9U2p8eykYcUXyWr8LE5yrBYN3tLqUJzZQ2NgaJ3QsaVwnzZcocbQYOZUopjnuM80fnSkptTHxuk9mRguHPTGhaf4@FPTqwa5xbNhqjLbWdgeVihB6ukpr/mbp4WrlOmV2hdhbWMkh3oiGI7rgSm5VLAaY9xLeoKtvoAmcbXgOJK2xCfqM4qYrWdC/yt1CD60Bnm7@WN2pulWH2AfFIG7YEBTfnKFmFh1BFHNW/h1QvLM@m1nLBnSxEdtwdL3RdrgT@eGB4fvI2zPWvgeOwpvdcRqOcCFfh7OU@HaWkZtkKj7GHzGjHkL56YF6gx6DmDfLGXMuC1stQnbhdFv/h@qJALhJSm3SKkfA3IsTXxXSnaz1Lu2W0FRJvHXFw4GzKuaWWXSSoxqbM6d9A3wBnB5Tk7SBcpppriY4grEsa5nAtj5n9/jtZjFWn91mM0I40aFDyMUCqCYexyLfvnSS27PrXOhwmlG2ALt2UiVLhnAxPaK3rfKFKmp7WPjKGl0x8uorqDiTkxl/Y1jlqvTNyHvKaf8eFIpUU2NsUUAM464J6XINQb0Tn8IKyxqUbbWmFiQK/dvF2bWRRqI1DAR9h7fgKGJ2i4GaNnT0YLpbrQQbOP15OsP/KrtNNZwA59PlYOFW9RlhZUdM@k39pOE@/k4cqzajadTgsdJjSVs2BZ15nKBHFfWfy9kDC5zFOeh8XpOzdkXJ4GkSW8tnGlCNJX9e0pcKmUsi3bHM/w/YHStOU4g48pKRCqHQu1MVAuaQ3vuhK7oe6I3SlsPnrh4ZhHq7tq3IK3NqJ7CfTBfvO6Qg/PNX1QaSo4mzrEma5F6/oRnNDM1W2p4H5wHBbiq3oHq3VJMSCiqUW1sLbWcQ3VaZkDg3@m@ew6eCU1sxbeotAQs8A4a8zniudz/JFrQmk0A2JZHeio9M2hSdY1ir7ReTXx/M/KQFMHf6u8p6bZTk33zfaqACML5IKN74XJ6ZCyNHZs6GKNcQEhdlUGuERVuK6SwP504lIiHw6NnskPuVgnKedjFrhMh/fs5sbloxdlvjSnDdHmI8yrWQIq1Zk58/zvUoCPZm0o18nw9hG3a5W/jcOgH1DbV62NvdnE2n2nb/fNPl@QHthWVQ7gxzE/lGQd6oB1r49r5EajhbXzYXoOnMHgQ@iJopELSsfpLsVpH3fV4pawj4I7M1rgIT63jt8ZYy470LCy1vTNCbRLnjN2RqZCtlVBBzjWw9@rZKg/@/3zDiKt7eoDRfzvzwv/1r5lz3DGoxF9mqPBxKMXRVVoM/RtelOXr3mh1ZaO21PfOMOWKhxVsSCGJt2Xi5iWNW73cRM652yz57Tafes2pFumMbats5Q/6sOtH9R3RcpYTLmPzurAAvK6MxX5pRr2f4qfw1WFLgaQeLMWGNboK8sG6Wi/tzIyztoeHxBFEyvjmHCoNvJd4WXaTl9@PbHGc6ChRVLBCC@fmUDDKtzFsoyVmhVtvpiLYbFcYyWXkpKOCrlipkHh0VaOLy0soAtVsUyGv1YhFM4lYRRa8PIx5BaLimiA0AoN3YL7An8trIZa2sjZ/UnPuykw@Yh9B1Q0fK0etqBF0qFRa2izDFt8VpFZH6Rw9yR8m6BzTcy10yq5tfMqFE4bKIZjwacJHyi6ycoxtIE18vibKd2Vs3FikRT0xa9PGXLazJZ3pkXBdMwunwVB020q4tCheVrQQZQ2zunjIDoKc654ccFlOz0Q6sqAzQP7YVepLUvXHy0v/qDNVL54bPYMXMT90BrjKtAlXEEsu2zd0q2wvzYxPOtrE8jZKmbDoyD4TKQbPjMAbUvgPTJ6VvvBQkEESAoCiyWk/LPA/uh0sywu@paHa6gCw5qBKWQ5zsTIdU3oNywJeX3oPjgFY16B@P7KpaGXDa87oxluQ5uRad3IujWmUVbxXdV1XLW6bC0SF5PhaOKJz3IcaJVWeBR6eEbu3oUFwJXXIFpZ3xiMl49Uh4ZcQQsTjeLcuEob/4Y1cHrsG8U0A6UNlDBUzpcwzj1onp/g0iDXXsKJlPYHznziQIfi8oy9hrI1M0yxbGu8fjRnPMZlQv4XM8NbDtz6kHqIb/Xux0JQTpZT5OHtuv58z/Mt7Ttw3lNn4rZNNAYHmYS7BSJVc89f1oxbRRw8iOUi3EtbO3sDzaFjT8aKO7HXtgr5ta1CmU2L@RAbsNjX9h89i4e5gZaB36aFmtD5m3iD2dy0cs3ANSazbFDEVsvRxdB@X@I@P3fpmNYg3xJnFw@HapO4vu8s6@88mbnm@IM7TCD8J8P7ZhtnDm9N@7HzyLEdaI1GICiHxyY/TGBhrcfyiBjtIW6XB/p0bk3mKYFd0QhxbcMYmS0o38Hc9CFtEQd83xgbK5oiGhuk/l9gupVXrEHLdF/RoF/IvKpLu4jQA3NKfYvVDMProDJut7lKjONxC3VkYcbGGzmOzd8kbdPw0R6tlyrQFNDrw@fKVVzhvzAusLR/tpjVo3O@UMTs8NMuVuXVNVvOgL/XLEuyLb4swHAt00s9xMMTyC2fZQpoX95aGVJYK0PmXSPQZM8Nj@bpl3c15iC16UesAuobbtvBmTBhWLNAJ3TiwS1iOtg0wNcOtIDwU5BYRnsiDm68Da3BsDWk18oOQ6g0j80Wbjdq0TEhY2N6szD5yJA4IyG0qCs4WcAXV1ip8yz2BHoj8dubrYV@1CJVrRG9SFKvnC6n9TqKbZntNwaOmjlEr/nY9II/5Dn1mIwrxqpD1YhGkVMGbaFfWpMWV6@BQjMwlXHfhT5/arxueNs/v2XJfMhkaOIk8@IszErV1fH6lFln@Xx6IFxdUxFnB4IsCc4R5PqhsrtS80Tw8H9076spaISb@ax/pgmIrttn8AH5iWuLz4dw4BPHG3et6RHgjfsOVokTzFYOosCH1ww0ba3KBJSePRnw0YdeaOnVsEPdMYUOwFWUAYnrsamY9rlCJ8xNb@bI4bvJUrt4kurY7CjigAWcaVAe@hvLgmDiu2QCNSwbcb2nluKEneazYgXoMuJe@JIB9C1nrIw8@qZG3pPDh0cn6sjTlrZPu33cj3FDj1s4sUEvpkNDUq8MNzTfyVekdSxvnLr3VFP2Hh6qGGAFvfmMhgIfnJlb@Kwc9xTnlhopY2UvCH3N8XIF8cHJo4eJ@d5PFtvru87QjIe9954@TeLelq8@Xeodjn0AtaPrTFdGP9zXtPgS9n1m0@zgKum5JKVVkE5M6I0CMz7gB77cqly1nZHZOZmNzM@h8UQJ7n1g8vmVmXxsnFs9rIWstJJQVFFZSc1n46HF2dDZNt3gu6o8z6wRSss2fVL8s3I5CmoOmZSbWa49rJvxv67FsLRYifBxkbT0TW4dWwrUjF4fTSnD@4cipmnaKjo/NbpQriy3srAWAyybHx445x8wlWyKzosSOClj4CrFunUpeUEZguhO4QuH54UjGFsrl8GsAxA455dW@AvTnhm2QnNZ69SLMsTGRW1rg3zD/IAJqWCFzzmeJr10ji9YVc9ibTLGb0n4xA1F2du7d3hbhGNBy/WhPn38jD0xPDzdZH3AMMbmB2A814xeKThuhUfrrZxO7bgASl8LrzdaXp/L7Knhdhx7Nr19Eo42t2LTTocVB7DQRoHMgTW1lrVVbT6u9WT5MqPb0ub7OJzZgh4cPvVGAHr/nX@uaek0nWmEXy3NrbeUjF/BWQxNxgwPygt7nRwGoqGNeosKDvGlvdGH5hSXo/DR4GWd@qXtW35N21eIr25O1vkV1/hl16R3ww8dWUZNa2sA5tb4sZwaeD90Bhd9R90zXNP7wDIJobYuS6U1WSqF5PSbYhqHQ2mKUZhXK/u4j0F8lvLtiTl2s6O@07Kyt@Rmt4snWrJHeCD7rZUMN5TR4peeI/aEcPtyHC4mt0moR8Yb80Nk09ntAtTsT2hHxZqAfAva8cQOH4rsJcWxFnznKN/L56n@ydWxmJ1IxOOLNyuEdy7yPXt4dB7fbgdh375lG2JXHXgEGw3FXj48YQtUfBN3wEoEArdYxuxqVcuV2A7eb1CGBjxOKaITnWPkp1Vnm5dii1y5rF3hNkG5LDOxhTE4lpQfrQlw8VBAyBNTzjS2OQafTX@DHaPD4dlbRp0C0EK0XBpsaiq847kidh4CSpuXTw6f7D892T159rSeblzJcbG/luNm25Cav/P6k0xHhrwLsoGw4Qft0g7dASRHB9djZ8Lz88UgZ9eyVl3I2jxT8g7G2by07VSKNpqmlCvAT5F5auQLmgM6cdh@jql8xD7hMt@fOSCSypsctExpQpmVWXpZwiMDKsmmLfyv37tBviyTQV@esDgbFViy5zgdkaJnstsfP8WD3cOHz473mY/gnGkurM64Xy3l@NG52CArJpRT16I1K1UWFVGiUFbVavQgCoSJqlFWpu29dGwt8DkE86mDG4NF7C0W2yT4QMFoUCip//zN1FVUxeWXcQgb9ZGKMkF5DMBOcMven/@4w4919w/q8C@YcYfU@tCBCJLYjrtiMy5SlCrmaPU1M3SMOu27Dc5vn1/dI9Gp/sCVF3TG1rXzl@J0JAq/M0gcj@UnRAziHwWN43h41JXrsXMLN91yHLp48tQiK@PUP522prJdvEMHeJ4ZdLUAoD6xx/x0F3EWRAT4SA0ESpJtErL8IgI5FDC6vQGs3DJ7ls08GzpH5rjMXgGf4VhZme/8VpRa9EYUHzS/PEnpj4eDUMAbR1V5qdNx6v2vfjfVqzAwT9P3wPbLwtYF869w84sUlvXN46zm6YeRwCPoBNY88YDmSO/QdUE232E/JxaeuuVLSmYNoWjOidIYnKfA3woI2DmcWP1zKChgMSglsbOep2e6jRiegVdOpZCNsHFVaTWxOeVLe66dhZfP5bNaCpBUzn2AdHh1D7ctcoDxeBkYXzq3RtWXLWCv7W0mo65tVvMVXpqpTftFRn4ZILoJYaWLPiJXZxAHosxjgF9NRIPmJKHFMSrKo6gWRVHUcaCdIX9sj9BuC0LILAbE4jQy8TTkKd4bNXZn/pmOLbyLKXSxwaYApGjQypApLktiM/hjZwwss7ANnm8Gx6VtvE3Dw9I8fi8aHaWIPKjerE3zPYz@DQqifqlY7zmoTPp68xguW/k5gniKIMryMpatv2Cn41O7keK8yYBNfyhYNszMNph/KdVbwbM837s3D9KLXT8GD4nF7j61HexUHEBmWExP6ZmUlo/Ps5TNLs2SyJFIBrKDx3u8heRANIGYaJvWK2fk7e7tH3716MnTG4fFUcjo9WAgyWvbiVNFTdYbgSEaztZikdw7SD19dO/AL4g50vmQBAbtReREW5eT@VgBgpyvPb@etWUYXs/daoyf8w2q1/HN6OtQo0g38NDSH5Eurf9UDmgXx/XE9eIyauVy61Caw0uFQO/xLXg3UI3FL6/qje3aqR2J3uSEJRXhRUTdwkoAplNvazOFzH4zc5ix4P7CE7w4yQvXxczyuihvZvDMItwEPHbO5qc1CYeQRyi/fjIgIiU15QddWfuOuNY9P1NM5/cr8tONwme6hBDOp9dRPATqxL@qEaXI/EREcRhgH3rsA6sl@Wfp8EMB/bPLgvMA@Tk4sbgkztXnCcfE5Y3T8lSlxR6xOEo7gpVk684X9OHFJajQqK89mUA/6okz4ucs06TefdM3HTsgfu9P@OoAk311MoRwXfocmzTACpJbgchAyWiAKtefQEqI4wWnCTzAEdKr4yGDIuPqsJOLTeNq35x2rB7I9lg8CRLtE01rsOAIQsw0HTloR2Uqs3kprK2Kn@LGyjDZP@ocyukcAaNuqJbdMaex6EU0Xm5A@ugevXh@Ho3Ly3iJzsMUB0R2rh@MGaBf0NZLEmMsaqd/6uQyaVEq3ZQS4HYdMD/Ryb/kpVRS@55Ed3VVURd/OnYfghHUiFh3aIxYbGLzU69URtbYacxO0jFBSo0fnGezRIK6SPAhD5VRzC6ZePsdM@wZi6WqwATo6tkd/LyxRqyuqWoDzJRInG3i5Ut7oHHhCTJxCXq1EKVMYKvIQtBxAIx4JVE5g0Mc9JfwYB@Xzg5b4k130dA4lIM0oVyz2h0WukNrUXOUS6WyKNBFqVhiwH03xaGaArA35JyvywN1xQkVQDPo0KpSZC7Ib0q8CKUb4Yg8EEdbADqR0GGX/okXDGDNj6Js9138xfZtqCt4SE/52clBsxhPySw4IqPnWh0cJ@XnNQedNnHDBlTT1ELQaIX30T7FaHj2WZOfwYFHcx1QhZGvidRImAzXr6Sd86amreV6EVGUAoTMYgMg9hE1fXB4yJ8/Y73Eb7mw/9nP8NJbOba5k880B@eJaC5dgZdWybEc@2TzVFE265qWTVfvbhrG@PWpzIxUduv@udnvtg57qVNZZhmWTaW2ogdbTyw9/@L19CqjFV@fjbR8XX09bcjFavKsMWVPnnzxrvkuLk/PZ/JpjLFChLG9o7eylsXOaqRcYCWGv4XnDb7oTsqlz41euhyVWeT0FC@zlQtyKlWPNuCfvF7CwwPVa2pN3Wm8exevFyBP0xk7jeAFkezoLnpTP4lGmnQ9/tSyrBQ7HXmdDvycPmvwW44j/EkkYgoTDkqdu1WG0y65TXfNXm@yb8y4uxWZ4OdgLOI@@sbz58/R8Jwe9uY4ImBziH4a5aaRizA9rf/5TzaukpdPmtt//q1hytzAzxF@vnv1CM1PtdwnGxuf3LuXzSaBNtz85BtPvr67u5u9n8w9qed2skp6Y/vP/nRjQ9e39dRGw/O0RrR@dvaFrKezsvrnP4o2nzz5mufVMv/HN9/VNHwV4HWOJYNPhmlgxHcRfhrqWGfsDTxnXYb/ZH7TCZkNNLe6b1jkTQS4XIvM6K8ZCcpsg2m1ncJ/@f7R68g4UtNTz134jiOvI/lihBvBALaMbzuP1CLbGCx/FZmlqtUqGAv/5d9C/NpXAQ76zLbhVcv5sPKzSE2pUpS3kVoeDJquQ7r/1ze/GWIeLiaqpMb5z11Wh0fOFnR5pwHPFj3bEh5MpqRT1PdmU/9hWvGOdocxe9wfmw5@LP6xTTwhWqlAr/u4nkgkGqoCj9qk6ClN009BALAF1qLxFqKSsHIXFnYL@ES4gN/zCPEUMBXxFTcLB2I17vD8erjnS57K83/s51iK5DfumvdrNRCFmVpmq5agZ@O0XObkT7FCUXacuzLbgjJL0@shvJFeNZmli7qcTCbvIiV1pKmiC/pFoqdyNBJ5OSepT9kIm9tY2IneVBBsHmZVOMaWh9vH5y/@17/4wV98n/5@QL//gGe42R2rm9qCeOdQdWr8ga9cc@XLU7JAhtPlYrmYal6dxrZAUjWOmZb@9G00l4k@xVYCb9xl2mlcjHBGgqdWwxf9CxuZ6HvNTfjUAguFmEdZHw45jdKFJlgsdVPq57WGgopTValr@VxD4fzo57FWYvW7UEqyXijJjZqe049qclqTebn1Nz3mCHEQ2YFnA/7oH57AuoGjyBvktuH7UKibz0aQ7q0PwCxrW3omlfskv69LkXo91TAboMiymg/k7kZ5o1jOl/VUcw1cVlkGG0oscq61W63Wm3bLgKdltA1tbEzuqgW1qOrbxtSYGePWpDVtjduTtqZJkXf1DXbMa0GDJfznNHHr80xVm8JIBgd/iuJMI1LkH@GpSSxyCU/j3Vb93RbwQC2xTRWwUVMEIvBRm3cbCeXqqq6@SFQq4n@7Fhgr9HAT4N@4SiS2X9QUpf6iVk8AyBcCpMphqs1aY5s8grREYsJ7u8EgvcR2PZp1onnn7nbV2aMfxIRHaQDc7QVc795NoDC@CwBqm6AqxBOJTUXZQCldF9IIAjdqCT9TiAPoL9vbUMRX21e1q/r21dX2Nvxv0/tKfMH1avvGP33mz4owc3/AqFY7radqp6lTwVgNsKupGrqoqVMw1OAL4aChkiJQ9cyyFNliW5ER0wqZyJYUefn@y/8Zf6fvv/wDbMVByypJkdQWKv8l3geAl/3IZo8ePcLfIxss@HvEHxtd0OFRDR1t/iIXlkq9VFlZ4cfKa8V8XEVB13S6TdwJqrKXj0CqQeVnsl7My82ENtNZZFvOF7D6/8KNJxqN/pOXeqkQ5V1l3Lz40nvk4yES5ohB0F9Y9vyTX1j1SJG3oGCC4PIYz7QUARpHFKUmRWrbQ1zEhmPSCqr/n1e/UJ7tKthfNcY0y9DmfbHq4X61VKrx4fTNJ8QUW/e34K3B//6G5@EFnpjMJb5ar/Hv4Rv8ez3Gv5M2/h2/xj928gb/jsf4xx618O@Jh38nr/Fvt4V/J0P8u/ca/x6N8e9ZD/@kSBUU982d9CDdTmtn2hkYLJZ2Wbqf7msdaCmaGkubLD1Lz1h66GgdMJnwlwaTle6ydI@l7bQNAcEXTGOWHqOpC58e/HUBkAt/Fi6SONPSbQYJDbAZopugEDyY3oIUj59KdeiTyi9N0LNVTU2reauBR@jX5YZeKjIVS1Jt1l@eRht4NqteyrLWzNw4fckiHujolUjq9DTFRxuYnq3gaftXV83m/uP7zWYKJdjpI@do/n90NAxb1/4Pj5xHR87Qgf@jo6NHzKwl7iag4t@9WwVBID47kVpl57RM4sQXKZHU9s5pLaOgOZ9A5QLdEh/5zCHCt7ZxKkUZqD4XFVKwKhfnlYsKGQIrGJqVIIAIxg3gWBGKGbhUfA3tAp7zC3LEFxovnp8GJm5IPb84xY4G9CCDf9Bgw9b/Cv/W/7v@Hz1jsXoD9KXY5dV2jJ44/sXjl1eXV@Jdi8diwhLbhj90ADtGubyqoZECXYKpHos34ldX3A3esfg2B1jDNLZrFHkeEERAJEiT0uWv2H/dL6YtnlM8xd2YT/2fnk7T6Xil5Z8ajdNexluagY1X6A6gzVZda/zZj@hs8J04BcplKxVti3GLntUrlaxvKxQrlaJv2YzFSjefWnpHy4PGlM3G45UKWHZ8sGmwBmCLANa35ACq6RltqveVyOXhEZ2aDWIiF4ljjrhgiKXpcH28pyUql@U7d2Li/ted3fidO3op/fZt4DIagZO24NRsdiy32UT3zNu3clOmqfhSDuzp4tu3WrqU0KJxx409xgt@IKmYorFP9BqlWnJcIEUBvJmW0ud49A3PGI/d2BtrlJRxyZcnx@n@jXTacU@jP/3et751Gq1WZUUm16yGADAVltvezmdrtXwWzPki0ErevORX0fQSJS1@tZmSOT2YvBmNCC@tWIhz6RhFf2hL2U4NqriHz@VVhMqdZXPxGIjXOChoVxH8485aqcTds/lYMVESf9WNeA0UBv6H/d1MIrtV2LoLuhT@TZc@KJIrl2ZVu6pemmUcN7yqtMXdirhD1LxzJ1MCmhbTlVOp2by/e7LbbFZlWcZGEV7oSMJdwiudRm60TgWeKzXqmLvGaTRartwl5tCKORaJVkQ4JQqtBCuWiAiS1cXt357HJE2MJmxIOn3xJYnxpA1wjGCrPP89ebi7t3@S1LcVFtEPdveS@tNn9yIaWnNzO3ln0H68v3v/6BlEePJwf/fp/qeHn@8/ewLuHruYP74EFu/5N2xaYr9gz6VX7hvDNA1zYprNi8nk4jV7ZVlNCwg7mFiW5fRc5plN0zRHEMx/KvBrW57x6pXhjuhh73/4nfc//G/e/@733v/ud97/7g9@@uUPvgO/H8Pve/z7vX9TyuH7p1/@8997/zu/C47/AX5/DL@f/PTL3/gm/5H9T@D3n0JufyJ@oXD8JwGsX/7pl9//0U@//JXfhN@/FL/fvPn71Z8s//3g26t/GO/7v7c@zPf@Lfx@n8Pyw37vd7gbfm@E/x0e7ld@8/2v/zv@/2fiD42/@/7X/wRfwvLPfvPP/tP7b/17XS/@2b9@/@3vv//2t95/@7vvv/1P9fe/8a@1dPj1e@9/8Id//Ue//9d/9D/Q/4/p/fsf8v/@N//ZX/4vf/m//eUfid9P4PfvwPSTv/z3wLB/94c/xP/v/@Hf/fEP8f9/@ld/94e/9ne//D@S4be44f/@l/@Gv//mV//j3/72d//6J9/821/7yd/@1h/@9f/@K//nb/zHv/lv/@Bv/vtvoeNv/eSv//iX/@pb3/mrb/@Lv/rWlyve31n7/vID3L/8R3D5cDw/BM6H5OtjXb78ufD5h1BjngrwCXD3L73/jV8EBv91xt5/58e4zhl@K/5/rGsU5sfc9v8Bg34zz@iTBhP8fu39d76HJPrvgETwH9Dru4FlwYdbvju3AFl/e0mkX/rpl//iR2SLmOUajRFjO1rUi4kt6GtslUqiLRXDxxDlFxehBQBESt9FCbXg912Ube9/@M33P/qn73/4W@9/@MvYiinZUnI3qWjrFy9C06fkPiAcBsx/SDgM@AWmn6BhFCXxBdjYF8Lziy@@kJpvU7ig/u5bcP2CnPjDuBcuuBdevh@64wp89paFzcKYFsZN4RqkTFhgqgnSALZ89SSXYdOEQGiKI3p8oB4DTbf4mD2@yRW9pxK@5v9z41RiCQwjxvgTcyMZRDyRBDdKOUgmMZ365CJ9iXEdZYu70GwUpZstMczBdJqYQkcUDJBCArzuJVi1Wk1gxCrHB6wctVqRESqJRBXyjbF5nGSziCCm9wgKxKwmjllzqzrlERMIr@aTIyGh07Gs6XKiWL0PCVan9xnCQuAE9uXLaq1YndYQ3DtOj8Q0cY9wQmDVxLT2DuxVggnxpMj9d4BKsZpI1IqYIGaSF0@yyQspR5mjvCdYQpQBfHGAd@cuY5/IWlHmMyMbSDAeGt@JeegdmqrbAf/TxJbIDv37RvptEcE3KCmRCuP@O6Qh7nClEQMAXEVRVZXBD@f/dthd8J5yUAlKFj4JDiFBHEEcEDgAG2JZJKh8E2SB9CPVrY9@EBhmZnNzU4rU5Ix8RBNFCeiru2dlfoXMW94hKjM5X5LR2aQF5D4uEL9C6W9GcVg@yjhg9kmC/@7e3WKfQDbpO3eTmJLIOFkcjUco24mErAP8mpOQXkDXQAI@JUBvJXVapYmohJRMMqZWI@jHjo6OBBLk8KIqJYDN9YyGdpw5mEwmEYihqkk1mRRflb7koAqDSr7iq24icWl8kel6tgLdlwpDJxbubmjQL0XHd@/eQanQKo7yIfQYmVjQoWeL5AkOfD/xYDDzNxro2ZLEu8tMy2ehK01XPcITZ3GJxdhWXOLrfTkS/hOL6sVilMIB9dXYlr@@J68RO@DQYqSGiPoP78EVc3Hfc@@I7R09erT/@GTUaDDJpGs4zebIddqm58XQb/fxfb7kXy/l45F6HUGflHUUMNJ@OU3i7/D@8eHTMuOZFkUQI8QqNCsjslnSpMho9Hw7ItY3yHjniyM/xXd5nreYXspA1EhNirRN7FEAL@E//CrSI693z5lCRzwpy0ktj/2rOA2oMunrzoThcWR87zLUKVwBrm5vEwWk2qVCI9pohNLKS7WaWBnENKn2dP8EIpwcMU1Pq1LtCzZVMUHlSqoNqgPT7o37m7jERj5Ny6E8bdbTSfzTMxl4a9l8UssVGhsbg0sF0zylYrvEtVJXYL1UMBtfgYdJX5HYV8AJHkgDF0Axsfrs8KgilgDhwR8xvg5I1nJQzeLSKRQ0ByeNwk9lBOwNfe3QT4psfOMbY1arQSdXOTyQIiAu@sxfBqNYHbWvUjl3Jq5Jvj3GOtbnFt7mo3YsbzQwZlB3gByRq6urLkA6PGB6TScrj9HB91WbXFpgvpoaUsQul6vvtGxByurl8ruMrkvgIEVevDCMWq2eblxmC3o2l83pmXw@V9CBaKVsPlfMpLV0Pp3Tda2UzZaKpcIVi0HJGoZSq2b0jPT/Px/00GTC9qgG5NxOjcBogDG7nTLA2AJjbjvVAqMFxtJ2ygLjpJbR0tupSU1i0jY/e4vh1t6qPDaneNQfd5NrnjnoqrhtoCpTArq8Lc6yrIl4Ndx/4RidKu7/xHXzsfil1Kl2nDbdQyZ11JbTmaneeDbA9fUDx61GQbWK@h4WXu2Ku@KqddZQR84ImkA9V0jUtTQIYvxpxaSe7KjtgWm4O7lyroiWYIpkJ5cuX1h2x7lQv3j08MF4PDo2aQn/TrZU7qh4wAZuhd8plnO5Rr0uy4k6JdPAaw15LVc2NqBmmEZHgW/XsceeohcbELljudVqNLqT0XRFK2fSRekqyL4EhMM81SSMmcC8JJF4l6IalW3HhipbThpJ65LyXe52u1dbl4m5RTIuFW4DilwpRrJ1GVgrSihcmU2SijX3BBejCy3KpZgfKst6rihX6pW5vZCXK40r6e7Q7FgGLtw/TV/ejJUH0cahRiChUyZdlV3HGZdbZtdxzXnAjJb3A3KEbgbIyldBcqdpTPHyZnJ5DAQ05JQDTuUnndVosVodxEBjH9rBemPbPwMNOVTXFT2jZDRFy@D/LQYd/z88vA7/Or4hVkaXTnAf8GMQytCQ2Owh7oocO@zEceh2vXtme0WIvb5Bq/L2XMfz/gFh7hn2Gfe6b/HDtwKvBwZeq@ENrXF/RYhnoyFueTTdfzQI@8MWIEgVmwLcg5c7cJxlAQrs2ZMVuXwUHHcJxODnXULw48NPH5yEvif7u3sPpDy7d/T4/rVPTgTKsYf7ByeBtcB9/ai5AMTX9x8@vG4Vn@zRs@PuxHHxJx0cPcvOX4ETbvSSsvAsBgqcCYh4oZXUFhw73mC5gm/QJFwqfAe6XneEMZefG9NofM53sVlesHSVb1csSyf@1jaDoQBqmazNd7ZiX5BOcRGaolYoSdKI2c4FK6RZxxkMDLyttLsBjn0Dt@yYqC4N6FJdTPrCcQedC6tjbkiPcHdQScMrGREJ6QEAGU7adGSCNZbwTLAO3iOKMxWtwcRkE7yrd4UjfNAJja7V60MDc@H4AaSWYTBanfJxD8Q3w894vcOYp0FuN3wGN4NLEckYG5Fi5c4d7YkLNaWWLpd7Zm1/CmzKnkG1MdxZspiT1bZ8wNRmhPWsutcYQVFlsnkNNS1QbzdO02flrMM2U86oZnjQGiWydVAQx912Bdq4XBmoDJ3pLDRQenovnXNl@YGBrQY2H3/z2z/@@z/9tWNWBLm3lYJXRJNlXK68oUkqadR6qZgrljJ6MVksFbM5LZ/LJTU9CZ2RQgn00bRW1PLFXElLFrOlDDBjCXxzpYIU4WvBUlsEEr5lAGu38f7AbVLK1T5o33zair2JGXEWMQL7hMkmxJHxxnhvTPsht6wqtDpMS7NMgQFEg7VZ5OBgL31wIMv30ILT9XtpWe6gJVdMpwv3ZNkkn70i6hKyw@MU8RgWecwt6fS9PVmecAB4gqks99Gyn8cRHFm20LK3e3CA6XTRomN8CHbGfbhl4FsKEMxGSybDAbwOoEGwXZ5OlhDdRwsmiT4H3GcP/GT5Ux8d9DnmwTiAB35Od3dl@ZBbdnfRZ4@yneOIfoaWXXpk2QUL1AtZ7oGh50KNlOUWGLF2yHIbTO2ZAW54VyMecmmPDVmecfIggWR5SqGN9pksN313TOZzgU0OqVsmi8ZzfZcsJfyTZd1HGoNlAktGlrOBJQt5e/Dgc6M/7pg9/sxc/m1DTh88yBjWdLJ/0Pr001av13Jnu/ufHqPX3t4DaPhnE7fVa4mIrSY8DsTae6AbZ8PZ9Qdyfdhslo3BUq/Pms2sYV/zas6aJmIIsV4DZuLpYULD5h547T1o3jWWzSISwCYKhiF8W/jcG8L3ntHiXv5DXvSdtlpyBdkflWS6yBlqIt2pnBwabdepoH1a3WAsGosmZ/V8ulEhDzYEdThduaIbnGP4NnDEIX45q0@r6UZ1Wi3ofAFKNyafTvWcJSc3hjtaKVfeMHY0PZuYlnGvtdONsqii7bCYdmfrDYs9ju/omWxZPt3ZUeS61tjRtWI5X3ixNZHleBnfO5lCGQKmo9Bdx1e8XmjsFHKhKIVCwkjp5UIhXrkCeoyhpW/hSEAzFrswjbN4HNHFfilkgd8fPaN8WpVubJqcVjlebBavTKtahZ/rxtI3YHXwENFJe@y4HGIPwE130mW6oVrWSkUZ0k@lYvE4yDsSTfCdr0Z7/rWTs5OTL0ASQide9Jef8GtPK8L66YM9FbrQwoaHf6oH2BlxXHUPxdWCDz@b0nc6AZGrPoCmFforvhvuf3Gdgbo/bZsj7NH4Hv6Rbqo4iEs9ebAA52kfOiEHohvkVej0CbttMjwb1eowo1oDk9FhMcKKGfELatSbtVq1WR3yS6ZrQazPGB0cOgdz6HHcg03NFP0S94QIj2Y1fVVpVaeRKcBpVpmivRw6nZd6ol3p4JGo96r3MHKlCd9WxayaeNW2HJEr3R27ytjE9oyu@cR0cYv@4dEmqBi4USTWZWZ8k53Sxdx7qNdfKTWX2XPMHk@GMeizt@KLTiErkib2NT/Ll7RzCWfmryrdKou9iFdeg9XdZLGOei@@k610YvdYMw4u6Zfdl12ms3y2QncVxhASVCKiDV14Ha/WPgOtiAM@K5cBEVHGZwATUwKwVoc8jPjIuqq0qwMWU9iUxYk82UqvWsfYb/G1rchyQ1HqbxtSTVGeSzWop5VZxKh6kxado83SLU1P5ytTcNMK2UofCtZ4Ma241dHENSsDsIrBI75By6gAOYFqAObN29j7X/xmfFvJVblbhUC9HYAi0lSb1WnFxpN5gCWqmSp4JOrZdBL6u/AqJKGZ1/NJLZ/MJLNJpYCu0MYnc0lwhD4PKBixQUxmTE6mp2lVS2qmloylX1qdl/HkWQwUGSIZiyfHzj7e8w0uUEjIlWSFr8HiCX1rwKAUHGZsK8SmICkqmDGgeZ@NrGQfQR2bxoBixOMKy2zFBpsxDLN5Mhnt1xvl8v509DXwiimvd/KJQjrxJh6vxDbiVVCGpFpFqqFUoVyPNoBnxbga8ybDOpTxeFMr6OV6vYU5LKSTmXQGMmc13/a25ZrcSKY38hqU0BUj7YhxgcE1pLmOM3droiY@MKHgtJJekVRawkEpajG9pMclXCUoYkojIdWQkCx2Kvt7EWPRaEGPRuPRCg56b8hilBNEGYmxKMjU6B1tRwb1Sy7LJR0DzCUibTdLhzWwKwkVPpYtSZFL6eryahv6uSlatIda5QaZFLV2V4qUGQM18FQcaJLaYOxj1wImtmsv@PcUFxcDXImO0ANdlBbomBZ2ztjnuLV2h0UBMcMd1nU906jrBWjIQDj6QXVdq@BAfwSXL6s1ILF3CfhtJ2q4K@UzNpsZCcUfeb7DWC@xKVGmI9cn83aru73j3Ypv28OxzFNJluVKVI5cRiPRK/iTIndpK4zOt8KwSGgzDA5m42Ax0OddhEQD27v0x6DKeJFLzChzQVBvxN89tgaXxYzCBxpAMl1dRTZTVCJiR0Hls5d6DsrIdvwtBtA5Qo0c2qhcDgdiI6mXI@8bejHz6PDIvu8emIxvMChmm3ItwtKaggv2K2XhmuMLj@VSUZf1s2SE3Y1UIuxMiWpl2oQwelp6UXhRfPHo2dGzowMpcrrxdsPBIXbmU4W9s7/6NehURDPZKGOn1ci0mq2IFVm1mqJt63hSUIGVQah3tbySflvj3Fsjj7wOPu9/8Tez0@0i2PW0BnZdzyX0Wk3b0lk8Mnr/5R/gERGX@5/vPmRRz5ixv//TH@mFv//Tf0UrnaJXFY8GhAsRCIlGLV@IXF6OLi@v4OF@uUgjwpHKFuJg5hMHWqSW0vSMbdsVVk4ZxlYhkdXv2pWUCKsVtHjEUyJiCqSQi3hvhZeeLoKXP0dBTnIeSyCyf2zldO3uNvKEFmyPYsHftumVgCmKj16@ZQws7Vqn17N0MqVSrPxOYdvvlG32DqcF3ikb7GW1htPKGm6q8kfNt3DzCE4dRWuJ1FaUQR@H1epXlUaC0bg7dBRfmOaWfXqNo083cFn7otOWDX/mlkd/GMl38MDq28ytV54c24qnUp2OOFBo22S5GrDCVgowO42//8Xf0PX83//pr75tvm1@oUMXsFTKa3rkZ9rPfgYB1mzs9/tvNL2AO/DREPT72Io7vqF7K0Xw4vcu4@H9XiD2@1BNsHo2dOvRJp2jakOl1OSnRXViFGwL9/0mSVGms1ziFUkKFEpShN1eO0kw2BbevwC1VLqUvoJe0H6yKghO6StzUOAwhBbTaTe9wcQd0Ur/GMXTGkl2B6JACl/Bg7g2aL@ykL4KCKzU1s2oHGWPqEZqEBuanofHekHDIX0Fooiz8vBaaQO31mNIywZxr2IQwpM8OnVIuwFpD3iEJrnGKPc8QJJx7HgkG5Rl6SvQ/hMVLFALmLUNASogYr4CBIA8xARgq8G2WSbOLq1EojI/M@wKl1Dj@WaGv61XwmgIrYPbyP3IFQwHTqCk4@1MyBeihEEjCzn6QDgMPtlbBTUfo5MN9Szad//BoAAWnXETo6yxO3fmWFWrVifOKEcI/8wa4eAVlYO9HFcA5neRPumU5STD09gqvmvAdkDxBKELXKfwY9gqoahMRuuVJMH/BzMtcuS1oiKPCmZAlBevFW0gGURGsvMybLPtKtP0QpwFyLcB9zYhRSeABf2@0@knqv6F73kFGP4s4p99DoLoJDwgKPj2@r5uBg3gBA@extN9uDAQ@7H5@T0o0A7HfuwgFmTFGlDoruVCn4Rmof3DwGIZLY7R5oenER60KFrPMlybnIvjh2JhaAZfA4@9Euls0NEdbQcK1Bs5Np2TRWd64MJv4AiQUeK4IY72xL7AiwpE2VDkMEYeHTWEnI8Y07lfdMMjxcVp4JYLHVefNklm9lTWHnaYXmIxYjQ6FskOwMUpEiHcAgUXadwamENA6alp0rYcr5xK9UA/mrTobKhHFvBV/8CCVsX2UuIyzdSFdWalTvCgZcXp4u4dvtM@gioVVj8@4yzOYRo4zhkbWGcmH@eNLZxT4DFQ8UFPTQJl5z8gbBmXMuiZJEuDd5KHgl8BPgVuLCZDcTdis/jNb0bbiDWxRN9SI2O5eFHmuWGH6EvPW0n0ar2Z5590Qud1gF0NRK4pzjioRnH3cnB4hyTObKnScSEqzh@MYtDH9M86QSOo3@Y5w/6phG0MCM22f2oA1mLI7VeoAaC6BzULjz0bu2U86wIwcTuxNlQ9IeBt9gnL6BIG5AfRiENjAAYWfXUROvhBVMyHN@5Awah8DxnIFaidww744S5rwX4Y3@duNNORdHP2ZhsCHDY6lFaV8WrhW3IhC9YO5GfK@gZ45gHDJZhsxOQEgE3IcZmDDuJfj865XSJZUmY3ISUZQhCkBiikKvg36bLQjQISeNwzPH5Mpjgg7eLiQqWT@iaupZoenrLv4fXAqVHPAu3YSY3N4UjcZ2bhPZYC7tyk8Ms18NLonSld11y6M@NfSep6VbEgJBbtelFsHM/xEPnekE74waN1PGKoA4suoGjHxPoUzn96I3np818Z@U8pRq8QCGMIZpqcJdtJAJZstc@S3YtORXicU4UE4FCKpu@Ip2O6vmXo@SZr1A1COGPaZOHbW4MzmgsFSDIfhZ0nzXPoh5z5VmEfWVOIZJsXbNd1jVmM/OMYGhk4NiO1h82g2ScfMEIzwy75UY3WtD5rLESfBtGhUfM7P8zF43uky/VA@bmd6D/l/lPwn3L/6TxRP9n6tMFVMnS6wuwg1@Opb35IBDPzw1zxMy7nPgQZdGymcRAYcrbgdgW/dpVi@/TmNijHqs8YwBMjILgZS9VfnNZPG7ZnXmw1EqkeMLtMhIASB9D1BtH0ohOYkfqD88HI8RacbDzsD1olgTc6tfuCGzivYB6DAiLG4PSy8Hy23lCsIeAKgcgwQEA9DDxRNdgdx6x4JTgnljyBcerynMYcsbpApkHal/ASbqAucdJzwoYBNUKA0D3IEqAJPsyvOfxOFV86PHfx6ng/rELXQAzxnKBoIwqUvFZVuKypUCGFsFIUH00gO6qr1etZ8f2hKOrXvELZvBLlH0Z/46PR70K9WI49MSxvMCpSuKrg6jdQIUR1IaqyWjVUroBBassYmC60XPtcPxWtNSSzlfK7GTwdzIJ3gRfFxkKF347z8qGNb7ItlwNWmFWrkMVZlVdLXi98knKCB9E8EW3mM4KIzwUIwEgvjWaKaNNwtGm1ygUHm66IdhFCckpITnkUHnq6AsmGiAa9p@CGcSyeBminuDxPBngab0ZBDRrJDG@LxSntV3iGGU53ijTnMoe4QPAQqtjIZ@3G0tTrIaRDQusaAGTEGwA6/Hq2snRd4GlKYAtkFCelL6O4TbABlxXAYCSCK/ycz1jAZNQHBoVfTlA7AHVXTtQlWaOhXPxL85@c9B39n3bTMb0YUlt0TCev/f2jODaQsqEKGtI@tHQWBTL2ZJ7Z4oC8sM4RwZtM@w5oda0Lh8WWKNvgnpqIqKnWwGmlhgYuTcFLm8RFxqNZ3O8/4DQIuztyxsbYyWbLvNNkEdstS5/3Gaye7eBZ76HzfUHX6zimZ0fHUKhtp2dbnplkeAzbmSm6HaY4TlwK68nC6HiSJEYjeTcWQXO@QlW32cRrJJvNGC6si5eDZbq0zg7ZMxqVsP8LplB8EE8C6NEo5rReme1x/HaYeBS1iHZitc9iRyPhGYVEdhnIsDbo/@DbBw2Gec6850iH4qIq3RrH6BKIvjN0eqD1TTxVwtjXwB/OYSNCxmhEuCSZgV3acuhAcqolsXbSiIuon310VPaZHjPiQXx9EcACMZLMvU5jpKy7JLnmyuR4ND@9px@P79Mwvk/X40u98Os48655lXt@XNKZ2BwCBJyjkbkdDcw6yK3ODXQWUAmcUa/iET4YxQ4t/eogprsQdFcEV7vAH8nA5oEtQPzzVfRfX4B@9P0PLT4D79Z9OgN5M8QViTG6TsDz5zNjEPwwHpciS5ILWPv@B6YFYfFmpANUIUCNJcFl43meUDFH0O32glPmfcC38DyutrrB97QEq8o9l@DknifZmb66iO43O@bAmJmdmAiZDMH1c3wMHTaSVx@WcRR0JPQc3teLQdsVD3yhGUei80DlFSxjJM/j8dVsxYNYAffQSDlheLiafuh/QzTjEF@Vj1ZDPyAajeBw7LmFw5@j2WjGj4we8FtVhBzl7Q8vSdzcfztBgA7iTJvkPNn4OvF5HAuy9AEtQhBWXcwynujqQ8TDZ26W4ceR6PacQuGGIlX9UpYWrz9YXuLWuhIPcYXPk3wK6cNY8jam@2CeC7EaBzYXYXsf14TcgIxLMNrtWBgid1lbYo59QyagG43T2StaleYSgRrEJEk3tqi7TfpFXMKe8SF8ccDpc/giwJ45bnKG8vOGY1riehZGPkNjFNJahAso6QAlREVOcoFGKJTkmyH45VWQZntlmu0babYX0gxqwGKSoUBSeyFJUQpYPOuKYGB2xyukM3ph3xk@68Q2PLZjuDhacRm1omUryaLn0TII5KgZLe/HQChHO9HyfTJ40fJTMpxFy5@BYV63om@jZb9aYAAXrGS4i@5ChKO9HS3vxeJX0tg4Mz0/XTVaDsoUwuxwK1EESIH5Bq0Rp9hsR2Rz7JrQsJFSmWTIMV4Su080DpOkXxr@@YUmdDECeuIY5xYFZgmmLTQaoRaDpwPNhn/w9pKaXBat@f7RAS1hCoJgMgno44XjEHhQwyPRRWHEEUNfmtGALyCIcrO8HCMWask@EB2ROnAoFfJi@kQ9lfSBToz86xC4MU@EbrER8f3yWgTBC/DD8MTIq/C8gY6fHGGEc7LxJWghUV9G12QKy3oRF1H64RKise7FQHg5tR@ElxKBDcl00OFocg4TGzmjRSYhX1xAb4Xj0KAcr5TIvdeikVQQNXOFNzmLnKFgCFf@@LrshOIhagsiCD3r6QavZUG7QLIYveayLqSp8soHKIRkDtRws31GNwTdF0YKx8VNktqKVc2QH5cnSZJrUUxCZBVPKZoYY5560Hndx7OLPq776sec4lhLDAGEYgapcPnqfIT@7nD93VeofSJcS2CZYr28Kb2pXq9tZa9hPpgne7MA0TPJ7seXKkdBCnOSQ@8gpJmv47UbKj4u@eBKPk80gH5N2/fJFvQJbqHb9b4Fh4Vagnu@6Himg@OZvppQNzWSwbnqKy0qpiTg8IwHmM6zth5XnvFlRYw@NL5tDD66gN3FAg4XHsKjDLjXSM5ruTuxaZXLvG6D2OYuKFK1MuOCnKZLg2KeO4K4p6nbYNoWHI6ax/ePHj/8OjS6hUIhLtro2Rw/rLU41hq04xwyrYcO2oMl3RY9iZd@4GQ3DsfTRfAbp7Z8Q5ZwYQ3KgAGp@Own6nhcyLKQPL9WdyEeDxuiqIB1Nq8GxoJUQlXHwCbbEnQdA0HMcWzLEEB89RbonaTeWpyut2g28fLvZpOar2YTFy81m6IVw6LxZ8TjP4tspCaeSxci8rtZLiSJDiBg94/Y8we7J@zkwT47eLb3Gfv60TP2fPfxCe49f/Ls3sPDPQa//cdP95m0sFAS77HCDiXQ9b7ZNvG6QTziLcsI8p4zmnG5E9uLc/enxpA9cNomTlNte8bwbp9bVNsc13isfeiOznAM06K7yobWGNdb0EVb0I1F5aZDm/5w@T6DsC3o0w6xzzt0OlbXgrAS9n1Hlun5@8TYwIISBHnrb/pNciUJ79SipUN0@x2uwLqA6AaEx7kbAGPw9Vd0v7rl8QhmR2WCcMHz0RQ82T9@9JThMQZ7R4/vH54cHj1@yg6OjsH65OuHjz8Feh4@PTk@vPcMvSjgo6P7hweHe7vkwBFIqwzPF3g18cZrUVAxOFGlfYYz3@oIij@wLY56owbPLgza/uix6MRG6WMZA@uN2YlWpImH6gtuuaSpAhbb3D3@9HNo85n5Gmc4/algWn8gP/PobrfNNNum1KCy1KC@VUR1hWZP0eI0HzGcMbzqwazQuQMxMieZD5wW8XQsk8l7uEYFx7758QRUl33QkNAGwEZQ/oKVKqMrWqLR5DaBrEFq7YGDBzzy1PgiQmHBqHf9pSYViSgm1sogUNyicGjjeJBWCRyA78FBF8mOXR6AZQIHHoBluQOqooe4doTlRIjJ@GiC4pnlucOr4eiApoVZIXC4Z1Avtihw4uVGRWqw4IorPKxhQBfx8FEeuiDQ8NqWRVE8Co@X1AwGvGKY/Ho0kIl8KpHWtkFIGYRNF6caxLI3fo8o@gI34Dohozv2WKwaV9kJLg4ybYtfgdQbGDZfAjVfukO8x4p4Lk61JtSH4Oog2vQxcogB8dqyRTyCePeFVmh@aDyIee9GioZYI0nX9/lL0G5D4N4NBH4eMABIWejptKmloh2pCMbpClaOeQ5wJI7bvguHB3buTNrmQgSxaiv2ynrzJi6InFzoJ/nrFAk7KKI3pgtq5f9T3NNutbEj@Zt@CqVNQje02zYJhGBMYsAkniWQ4SO5OYY4xm6bnmtsX7cB@wbumd0f@wK7//cR9lXmHebXPsVsfUhqddsQstlzJucEd7ekUqlUKkmlqhIdZbb7QxjjJFbpshWUgs2L/mAUch86yRbQiRNNc5AbJzao7asirqwN6ZCusdfvGZWeAxffU@s5MOVjaiWO57NzLb7imzeB82ESZrs7RKdxjtfIx2dnHh4i3QSofoGFMJ2Vo/JzMiJMeP1pxbLjD4GX962VNne2TrN/fPXwBj8WC3xppjI6xP/AmFgXDA865yODxSGuu@RIUzcvRVfnWFra4ElpiaNcAYN94EUI@7o39aJOY3Pj6e/oFpP@Th9vb0tcKouSSd6jGl04sXTzRE1V6VGZMyFNQAzZCciCrHfUF49gann9Bl1hsBeKQJEeyhHct6fuNZIiRLXu/KoNkkVeLym7W8N3xSZZVMS37aKPi9kfuS/OVmlp083FBiXCIKejRLSnIBdc1zBLoflqCtzOw@BAfj8e3NqD2PH08EPQdh6E9kO4ZZfuh8XTkgHr8WD/eAAsT27/J7DQdu9@wDxJTkPTnK6Z05vPaGvah2v8OtV3NPYADM69qEHRQI3arnp0RK3CKTtcwDXBxAuio@OdyuGhsHl/AmVB7uGWoSXFIMJ@Ij7E1rZhj4SdrxdNerOsF0/qS8KiTf17aDDPJN49okKuQTxJDy0s4nul2@GYpZ6cWWgJQdb3JBAV5ZLYfVMyKKpJwHewBwRk404zGmjNbGaGJ58wMo3AJd08XhubNvxkYc1zN17aOJyYgEyboEYHPUtm998nXh@vq3p4gYVhfbDBLVhJw3wD@4QjqHgAGX0/2YMPdIvqUjSy5wV2RtEODb/yyRX2zzMUMRIvwnktbIh1uTiWqPH6eF4tc8ggEaeBBlp6ykS2aIYEJeLpy4bZoW486TnJKQgWmXiN3xuTK6D42V1RXyzvxPNkSS/IzbE2T9jUFJZnqJ2VsIv3Z3qKttCrafGQrgqk7YNVZf9/quJZIlGTovnMxqhEgLy6svL8e7DTrVDFsz8Lm@eQtPwcXQ5gfx@DjCYRqfeBc6v7nkqPGeAB0rFpvRowqYKw1JkxpyTaTpORiR/gwnohQAbDmOPNiOlaXTFO4TYbOs9IJnTKMtUGYwjrhvKomaL@3cPVoUD@bn1Pfrw@HmyYCU0H79Aq/31/GAWxV54RjsX4hJ6syW/BcNijbOzPdIlQHHJjetDZjrzt2OCVW4WJdN5mtqQtvZPY7NZTugaqhNSLPl6Gitq9Ylq9ly0UzabuVvcqYpHCG7YTukh7aLuG7HkS9h5CgGQw6SVw@iAfvqfROvwHHDwFEshE3nwO0cb9Lm5EEVg11@hyGWkWKmVrId377ajZ6GEUD89@GgnbewYFSQtbOdh1Z2nW88VEeUAuGvQcKOXZWd@movANFboIKQmCexO/GxMWemooS8kHrrBv5Apr@dVXFrWu5428y9qrM2@xWbIFTL6N3mV0Nbxp/drpX1y3RVcM/nI@bk5@/02IlRfiOd5q94xjzBZWSzkK6/kS/q6JV3niXInga4qXe2oL4fO1eUIsiHgfXnwi@MY42jSvo4dEikvF4qXiQnSxG5Uua6tnpV4pX7ys9c6K6OQ3WiqNlgpLDn54BrMoyBg@ma@NznBONbWuQe9a4G2qdOuddA0R5BoCX943hmF/r7z/NqGNwwUAqsCkrTcp1Pki1Dm0ZkPfE78X3DhSTeYJ5FgLF0jWHHkFFdC7nfTJqI5phYAZ9IoHq9loTH8nrjWX968Goz6lqICDyFriNry15pQbU540CpClFqqwhHT/ezSO8zh4MMRfJ2xFnS3wcq2AvpOuAaKGJUkc2qe2jT6FiKj05aqdWZEfNJoXiATe/HtLxcTGBt0DDKwW@aTFQ1OOxpAcJvJn@IgHIPAzoNMGrIJW7hG5fVjQfHwv4AN/IR3ViPxkyEDeopUipqD5t/hG/k1UfgMIwISf4zWXL1WccuUFC0n2HSTlAoYtS2788ZgB3Sq5U@awsQib6yvFwMlSnGiE1Uoywfe5GyQn0wr@yRZkC/Q21Qyd3@XsRBI6p5ZvEdKSupSSNvGnGxdzjGJZVUxlNkgx911qoKYLtkfvAxhWE7EddLuANNNiLiYHPpJ/r6x/Sdcf1bDOM408p2en0rOJdJ/TGak4lw8TfJxp3cxkZ77F@e6EHWfzpuoqCVq8@NDTTR@WJHHe4kN5I3/Ur4dx5k3dlcyVOmEjkZA1Ur7M6H1OeZIooxlcp9c4XfL3sux5jWUi75tk/fhryQ4KyHhW2pqkuNTvhd3Xlrw0VqYgm9lATSG4OPY3sR0PSumDKcUJrOBQz0/DdrMUQ1kqKIlDY8be3Hhj@3KR8dpJo8FejFMDa8YYMahEdS4R4cbksAj1UPITAwTBREYTauRuqsITWXhigMVcT1S17AU5NcChaekhXkK/yFv8owZ7EjmVLzM7cY4xH3Pj2bs5SSASuk/s2WRKShN0F@GPslEPzCJx3ZM0xNlCYt/QAus6A/bBbqMa/ImWE6agUJJiiu46RVI6zlBQ7HtfF2LinfWP3KL1tgFr7EE3GIsybjMa5IVlJRzcR0E0ijCcE0Wlia4Ggy6eOtKC74ZcqGXMkOUVPG6JIRozu29V0bKH83v4JB3SoZAvDhDyDRqIxAnRVaeDzmToAdu/QdGKGpdw5Fvl3oQVGjBmni@zm3kgriI@NYXdfsdEgnuORw9SOho0moFvwRotgtWPxU1th/JqR9Kno98IBgyDKW3dsv58FTZ/3X6L57kvC/nnBYNk1/I4OO8/fxE7WAGRVMIyBvtbKbywLONsuMlnw1kE6Ik9nOg/Am8G10GvF1hlmDEoYwSL1igYXgct37IOA30IjHCRlfFkEv2w@1fDJit3YNHVAGZEL@HI4@Mw4DD8xfmZj4ubdFbmWXhoFZ82Q1dfhy0koPI4affxdJgOLDBMANMDC10GIyDKoiuSKNHZs8SF1i6XqIgCamCcE@NsQpOh1x@FTegZ0mRZXQDFxyBxZb1WChOor9ltoHOwPwsBdI@JKaAQUEdJD@FgyUPzH8JByIapM/aG6pkcSL8@jRUY7sEwBOkbE5h6hYoZuEMHH7@rHomjg93jT@XDioDnD4cHH6s7lR2x9ZnOuPGgnGLqincHeyBd9Gk6n5ofwAe7fAQlbUqwyvufReWXD4eVoyNxcCiq7z/sVQEagD8s7x9XK0eeqO5v753s0Ok7QBD7B8dir/q@egzZjg88qlUVs@Jy4mBXvK8cbr@D1/JWda96/Jlq3K0e72NleKpfFh/Kh8fV7ZO98qH4cHL44eCoIrBh1k71aHuvXH1f2fGhfqhTVD5W9o/F0bvy3l6qoQef9iuHgowEjFZuVQDL8hZsYbEmaudO9bCyfYwNip@2gXiA4J4njj5Utqv4UPmlAs0pH372JNCjyp9PIBMkip3y@/JbaJzlfIcq0C/bJ4cVDIWElDg62To6rh6fHFfE24ODHaL1UeXwY3W7clQU1t7BERHs5KjiCbz@jqoGGEAtSIfnrZOjKtGtun8Mc8bJB7R3cKGTPwFhAMsyFN0hAqMZBLYWiHRw@BmhIh2oAzzx6V0Fvh8iTYlaZaQCWlRsH5vZoEIg4rHZTLFfebtXfVvZ365g8gGC@VQ9qrjQYdUjzFBFg4zPwDpQ6Qm1GvsJ8OJHYFZLca5H3Smqu6K887GKmMvcwAFHVcktRLbtd5LmPobVNZQoYR91Bo1LU7HSnv50HWA8yWmNzGwdjY6YtH2wU4EZWcatsuOEE5h11lKhlMw0mGl0IrwmQta0gvOrTj3stfvoY6qLseLjMup4eKGMi7dxnFoP3Kck9StUIJOp1z@W67DRParXXe8xJRNofK@EVIM/lMuVbcTLBHDnjYqf9XWm@0aCUJvP5EEnGerhAQTmZOo/Y9O3xmXgilyuFchi6LyPgJXqKOJjkws8SgHRSM6OeI1IXCVpJug9lOxABR0F3m/WUU@KlpGUqR/Bn95t/MKTg/EBpDOru3I53MQSGuHvgaqGK6GQCPRHRiQI21SlHwXBrx0nb1aHe36/0@@3HNdVZSjvCPaBHcf9TvHzoJMqnk2XJ2Tp2FnG8I/UvpuWMPr8WZJMyH7xh9QyB//UR/TjKmw45gNqTakqUlZLpaXzjIujRZInZGgLdK@gTsY13/vyL9VPuJvLL78opr6/0995bKG9IMadhQmvRuXO6OfdGWeAAUaxOIAkoYyQkcsZZZS9ic58AxkvMNNN2ELLH5irLwKa14EksJC9anTNOnE2HoZjE3uQw28Py@@3TnZ3QXQiti/WVl6uFi0ddusXj38/Yz0UHJaijg1gHod1GiUZo2QbFj40Uoyg3DH7EwPncpgRY7GrTqOPGOdB220kLZlQkGFzI7xTp4cmenaAdLAFBeB4Yil@nTkyJQM4iaa62JrLxpiW@A1YKxEPSGOW7oR6bYx/ELYe/mqI6wZJBpIsRuFygXNhd0Fyz95VpqK0uaHAPZjFtxUfcxg3TQNSdZH9LHrX0pvkbaMXIzZlxPFK3U4lAYknaSyEsqvo8cj@QHFGpAKYoofBl18kv8HjZxngjsLdNaJReXQEZNzVJVFPHSujZaNrEvIZXo@DQdVUTRsCtfyuRIrGnlQn68AgxmggVPD@E7TxTQIu6jgi6SrJAvbNgiu@Madi8A6EU5QcK9@Bc2c1R0Ipqvgh8l1FpRAMSwc5Yard6DosleWzjmOhyJkg00/Rg@D/E2kyA/4G7DgBekwtIwjgoyhJUJlWsH0looQ36qDBON2IqWl@@hyDuTM75kI3TJ7ejNm/Bkgge2eiPnymsIdtZwYBkMlRsWGOX22SdtGArdMb25XF8Zyk17wcOELOFWqqmIKbXT3zaNnlqbMVfHGFy7omo8I9KCre8MbtnEY9bJlSW3nxNLIZnKvif@QWSQGiBzxx6QVbraY5Ky9HmZIDMtSSMeG0dMQkWJbe3XtqtyiMEJkJ2S9PvhShAPQm4jPdTrokpC/YPDcZcZFmYnFMUfAwBDhuk3HykSHrzskQsxsgnKctUobgPSKjG5wgugydQvXF0ITzlAxFsJLY6jCOM4ji1vWBtDSt3mjsSTOJHKqxP@lx7PmAtVoqh88BPiSGpru8L943JoBy93HNZhbLLR71PbRdxMpYLSHL450pzX5/CEvHBrYbcPTCieuLT1LpEPSiq6GMXwjzWTiUGgm16IdqcNnEu3eaZjjsO6EWhSP0Vmj5xB/UpMsALUQ5PMk4uyocYF7Fo5tK6RiOlwrC2YhTNoAmFJaUiLghVsXtLedigsqQoQFRMIz05oJsNqkePHfQw@@mP/wV535cAvVaQUtHJjVAki6QO6naoxiPzRE3fdCPSKMBXYEaEE2JAivStKEqzNEvJTtJuyY7jo6JsUupJT9ej2ZSZS0FFcWMK2sH5lvNQmcilZZlaFAdLLSwvEKozNpw3d27GaNooclja2Gf9rRIWedFROmpWjriE8tN/fQZn6SSv/Q0wtEDX/CMWy5BEWFcs@K56rScI/zQpuBTGAxbpk4UVjKtxgDVb7T16feIF5XqUIb9azZGUTCBHUAzF45zBKPu/Kl/0atv97uNTtgPG7BPw8jtY5Z4@DihR@ywzrB/E9F1QJTQMjK1JvEzx5fhMGz4rs8li0ZormgUDBzTTGE0nJQvOEwEac7RCDC@6JL4e5COkabLvFiJC1lJ/1Oyxyu4xXvLPi/MKswn@ghACrjNlAUF@5COyDHJcD4tTmU4fyiDgeO5yIqGe4/FXgLjV0AiOoZJYKyQmTJLMBuBO7N7Ma61xl6LYhAOMdBSsBPg7TWRQ5@9Bt4dDFLkNVoKrIvCWt4oyqcoY4xDiA@T@8m9/PKfjD0g8BPoF57P4pZZjEAirq2iLUW8X5FRRgEXMg8MSUaTJAYpFnZgFuomgNbHaajJ5Ml91CDLH1gUyTB7U1yJI9KBjQ/eWufUQeTUJy5OKgtiwaW4HbgEKY@c/P0MG3zPfpYGPx7isuYMBdO2hOwYSN9HqiZQCW9nTZnXmihzTOXvj5jl5cf2WoqApVkmZ8YtwY6tVi7kgRLy/IrHWv0hCGM7RT1p6rEQjfqDhUdS717ZMTMy2yxaN133u4bAzGwlmCwXW0Ta0gQfJ0UrjU@KaZIUI0sz4CHcvtKzZvM0EcelOo63Un3yHTrcR7PYbkpPKrq/Wzz2cVK8RoteNdHoIUW4Y5DSov5eq0PD6/dLEAmTt1d1khh1FBn1CT8aoFJk0lR6PIWI@yTuKXq0gHJYbwtoZ/bPvURNG8mpkKcqKRHkEumJgdvRaRPk0qCNxhcYJo5XuFpI6QXn2JvQUV4he45BhjGBAeKqOMjGeijW4MadleIjuh2g7dTRWqiAkgieNk0LBx30XxOMovJL5Y60eKhPsoWzIkMaa0iwq6BcD0FS/ubwWquPCcoUKWCIzyCFbtGUbLp4fKt@ti2QDyBwaUqWlr55DxvjiiXABv6YSfUxroHjqmTJxIhKDoQ6iQYYC7BL6XQD3q7i6i8cMsejdYMcRrCB4M8O/izJEhjOezWvqY1Fxq0JZnEluXm0uSK7yUVihuJ3JL8cirzUpY0rAAgYYyhfKgAEDGtK2OOhAIXeMTkvgajsIyhYKuCwhI8UFTW285yRjkSVGV6sGDnys3K8MmFkZwKBhcXsPDEisGaZnSWGAhPdTFyMHC9ntyfOAQtixftMcegK2StJGuqeYwLSfcp5N5YotYLw8pKDKfHFiptI1PxNqa/yRmo@nQr00RjWsoV06lo@kZqodnk5WTRREujhmrUmEoEUromwlgo/949cU8yQ59om1NhkJFYZ0j4b77uGXSbs2/y/RGKDnLLVGkPBMz3D1farzlesJIKyPxyAXSzQkQHGbv/p1irLVIWJvCuA4tIpZxeHN4S0YrVxqsdm4U5XRdrTAQrUnrbfFh@Pd3cTYV/PJ8rQ6DIYruTzeWTiczP4vbKtRlVS2M8lc@faV91ubnDzp@HH8xzJ/iCgKwHW1Q46gC6BQRH5/WGHb4ZAHCAr5s5KR1bc61@12@YVDHhCiZ0H3cY5ZTQEQRNQqI1ePh6TAohAygn2KzYQ2/dV6NF30@CFpoSijqGgNJoEX9vq9AzIgx/aaJ@tT6oIGApmZc0E85Zb2vyGMwjebEKdReGL3W@xebL9Luh2@574hBcKY6SAubt0gd1ds0Ces@AJI3n3XkUUj9YTwXXYNfyKMYvJ6whOTUzqngkVFx5j4x8Gncp44Ni1LzZMK9DkJWzmEsan9oTdsV0ZLP4RYJkPAe1H5b5sDJwm0SmdGaZ6OYLjJ8DoecGbufdJZHFJJyZp9v3cSNTZ6PoUrAGa7tJaQMWyp@6lltyTXRPXPh0X2kjDPMOQOGHMlceVQFezf55YvB6124@TinQNAHfsD0lEvgnl5wQinQHQCJTDD@iJUbT/JQvDejcVUIQXOHhZx7TcwQJ1LGBZT5ul326ccrks5gdLS6Jc3oKHbFaUt8piBz9sbYkdeN/C92el5ZWVIsvcHfcbfNxSH@/EFsAgDedS82K4A6@QVkK/MbTWxi6ez5XmveJ8vbSxWYxytfIWuvXD09//9d///m//kSvLl//Cly16qX3RmXzfz803v80/uyvie23nbGH@vDY/OFvoFJHL/kFRw/vVUbYRm4/6w3Mrw7OA8ZXsSNU@m6LPyKJC3e932Rj@CtJlXWSaUS4jv0Z8cxTJ2EwzML4H6Ed5Dlt4delAeisPSGQA6ATV8dA7zQAN8GC@AUoCLmgHyuX5bEUp7jEcjM6gT1UyMhIPrVmvA/RpiSMpoC8uzFjZsBcFPdSAX9Oal5tnWQ34DUd1yb@5L@@jzlZ/LBZPHbGYF4ueWLRt@imsvoKv7nwuRO9czgbbAdv2ICU@WkAzQxGFtNCj/QPdtZMit2XN05U9CEmFqaDM7AXn6d0fOcvwhWtRx5rD6zMFq0jokAmLZL7N9@6gW75Bjjs74WpDC4W63MVQZcaJiu5fXAI1IjYEiGu@ZIKs96FKPOkjj2R8yqkvsq8tuk2IACNZD9/u0rjHDzAXzfekzXNiL4XXHJH5PH/FubHIztCENqZw/TECdKDC28k8eRIuZBYstvI2WknNZC9ss32S@djWYRKMlG06F/pDGEzA1twm4eZ70q9FGnLz8YqwQ328YlRlp22/hWUUubzqjsKBdFeg2nFAfdO13fFIwh4lQAyHY/avT48wUhSoSFGpbuHLsiai1cem80joSdd06GDX55Mjgwi5Lw6M7dvU2HZz5CWi2IF5gJDSpnztRtiNZNSVIRG70xie4@2AjTZdqDbiczPS5@GFqSmM@22NtE@QyeQ8Hs/QlMxg2OhcNjyR2e8fDxuTKkxbsPIZNX0XWoghmBAJHHyy6lnNUwhzi2SXEEV0U8hyCC8v6E7k9Wjct7b2OcEuVUNBhl3BQZBgJ6JkcJvoqxQdY67@gU4wUZ4S3vo0UopYkrxoaSQh2abbDA2zqaFjqRrMsaMHjm0xqnpkKl6Qha5wor2kg1@Q5F2MESDrtqUXoHRFWH2F9ePs1Al6jcTkNOhaytE/VxQ8L@J4pqso2RrJUpegFuIb7xArWEd@SUaB4LlJhTOy5hxn7jSS17llzHmEgnxrW/xcQ4T6Ajq6wIw8Q8RJL2RhmZqh4jswfFEly3@A0O42OoDf5KYxQVY8zTivn@Tc2pfT3tmic9q7Pf3dJUykSFazbFZk5GG2klhyrMDMmPMSr8oqLVKhBk97yQynPcE@LAYJAJGcU/uSO7vNAUKnGbxG/jTDBEl0GWKSe7i@HILPTaGZSWKRy1hz7qKrOt95XXAFzK30i33IH1z@BSzUppLU9LDPGbYBFPnp/nbFLidRbm05/2K58AJ2Qp1gnB0GVzjfZqOr82AMS4kIt7Mw9Zz@nuCGBCHuxlGjCB/H0E6@1oR9TyLppCRFqBzmVI@l2QrK@MwTkB@oTOFS0cXF1XkaePiIG35PAMupvBQLik0HDe5zcP6M@pdYTyNCuZb2DmGORCsDthEhFWoWIavLV@7jUFcNlwXyc/LFNsZuJSDQvbmMMVv0@r2sXKy5/kIRF9HoNdNdy6/l02N0aogmRui8XEwtPBGFzdcv//afB79lRpnN5dynIfyOMr9lVtcy/AgP8PZcvV1nNjMbmG31LjPJwR4YHl/@7b@h/OafAA6mTDbgz@aKgrU6yWxmS1TkNrO5Cg@F5WWo93/@@ldowzzv2PAu1vm6JwixoqLIdqNHvAvpooqt5G3pQixWyDELYbCFIezN4QUNo8bLa3lS02WkVcV1ICNfKXsUOcWTYdaITIVYk6HsKWBlxAVKWEGWQSoTirYwbDeU2QYyb4ym@PrUX41gB/BVmnPoKrXpxtMITYbmeVsEHehwjbCf54fN/Gtbm3es28qmpKiWkLi1k7J27XnxfwE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ho2vj)

Both interpreters linked from esolangs article have problems. Haskell interpreter doesn't implement input and ignores
everything after first `#`. JavaScript interpreter incorrectly handles nested loops. Also, the interpreters have different cell sizes,
so Haskell interpreter won't work with polyglot even if `. takeWhile (/='#')` is removed.
[This is the js interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVdtj5tGEP5sfsUEVTGUg9iOUrW2cXWKGilVolaX9JPrVGtYzDa8ZVnuRRf/9usssJjFPqdXFel8MDszO/PMy85uSRk/PNAgzsH8bmrCCgSnNK52O8q9v0sjIAJpEUuokeUh1Vdr@sODu145n1z5bFae6zmO4z1EVRYIlmdAOc@5lZY727g3RkGelXlCvQN1YYwKnge0LD16y4TlTpG0NwyATkVYpcVH3NeyUcOLF5ASNEQRIS8kE0lgSwNSlRSKPLnbJbkAQT7TEqaQsgxEDgVnGRLjHHnQhcaXEoikUaBZCDmHiLCkhBsm4nqrN5cfL9/BL1dXv13N4YqSIKYhxJQUkLCUCbhMkhwhklZKSVx04VdyTT4EnBWi4cwrAXkEKU1zfmeMWGQ9C@m22tnAqah4tgB0Fmpr/DH7PUcrKZ@PHfUKDowBwsNC2Fv4MxsvavEI8bwmHArwYbKAYhmzXUxL8Y5e08SZLgrHQfgAWl6omRkyvyci9or8xppdFPYCSUuN5EwlEYVBSQOgC@KuoOhU@JEUdM02vm9WWUgjltHQtA@crVvyBxwGjjmfgLnolvc0KWmf@9pXGhendDjjNeKCWkzn2hP5B4Eh3Vm2Y240rfXbfmEMZDusGob6R0/Ims909ce0pZSekrzKrNbNUoRvs6ISl5yTO5/JV68sEkzl8dhu9lOR9CfNtwqgP22@ExkjtdiPWycgQfHvp3OYtG5hur5JyM6PCCLYkFJyG9wFCS396aR5GnpLxK/68ybGPLVa@Wc@YlNReP68ZVt2WlQUFay1xQWmrGV3UKv/jYTjKHiNNkvaPNdBHrcGjZ12o2N4e3s1VgRvsxINrVf9ABvRWmHaJkqJJRvEVp@vS8OAYMWbmDVdhjRJpsKwUYbLZ8sp@bzQJN3HJV33rOSqL6mCrl6@nznTg3SdA31DEL6atuonhH2vpUfNsO9EHi3Qzt4zdYp878ltZ92wnB7xcHnew//Xv//qFsue6tannlssgsZSPAgn/TZ48Fi10SjJMcEV9cXM7nexWkc/Yc5asNYssAYOg@8PbZEbCEADir8aa32YtiWvnrr00ZkDz@pYS79h9ePVh6M7mlY@yGr0EprtRGy3p72ZsjIloj4st5wEn6kw7dOa9FqWbmGLt49Ya/c6s0@ZJU@SxzRuvqmxHxY9NGeDtBmkyTBKz9oojUajk8FB@pNjMjT1KCZLKX82ELjt6Az4cnmkYyMp30J4ICaDhIS9If/OYHihJ7p2nLZ5hThKILVBAaeXIJaFpwmsJ9rgoCsrYxb1T6/jdu6jSi@ICX@NLl4Ka2KfmVWGspN/Wdlez2HpxlagFwNlB1VqOEZXcJD0bjgT1GoGHy/iefq6tdbaCts@exiV/VbdjdQnRfbqAFdRXk7g61c4lH2/6gFHdoWLGkvkUNE1n3bMNY5QPG4z7TGucOiFvPbBnc5PdF9/9hM@/bBq3reyL@VEdFJ88qioiuOTD56j3DBOJpFyV@fWEv2E38fqZ69e6U1hAECrZvbqB03PmQw@1rEfYKJFtZngZHNQ@Ur47lolyNKHmWppahZM8p1l/lGSHZ3D4Gbpym95vVy74QaW8pK5UufHqbtiPWViDfW3Xs/qxmS6oQl4jyvx/hHkaUrxBsgON0pD6h5KNup@hpcwh9nGkJmOLJx@qRin1jgqx7aH0IRvUPbDXRZYUskFjCsRuT/Kkb@@A6CIiXeS@qKwMP4B) that is used for polyglot. I adapted it for nodejs and fixed the problem with loops.

Treehugger takes the path of [HDBF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149120):

```
old:  --<^>++[ hdbf code ]
new:  ++<^>--[ ^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>] <[ hdbf code ] ]
```

`--` and `++` are switched for golf. After `++<^>--` Treehugger tree is

```
   [2]
[0]   [254]*
```

`^>` in `^>[+` doesn't change current cell in Treehugger, but moves to zero cell in HDBF.
Brainfuck loop to get [51](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#51) `-[>+<-----]>` becomes `+[>+^-----]>` here
because there is `--` in front and `<` → `^`.

**Golf**: changed all bf loops except Brainlove to `-[>+<-----]>`, in Brainlove it doesn't gain any bytes.
Moved Ursala up to fix `-[` in brainfuck code.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to use the flaws in the other interpreters to add them separate to the polyglot. The Haskell one is obviously unusable, but maybe the JS one can be used?

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't feel good about the loop bug in the JS interpreter. I feel like it's something that should be fixed, not
something that should be relied upon. But even if someone is willing to accept the JS interpreter as is, it would be very hard to add because polyglot relies heavily on correct loop behavior.
Haskell interpreter without `takeWhile` could be added, but I don't want to do it right now. (I said it "won't work" meaning with current polyglot, because I used a Treehugger loop that relies on cells wrapping like unsigned byte.)

Answer (score 4):

## 327. [Poetic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Poetic), 14787 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//     x x x x x 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<]'4o'6o@ ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnM M M M'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'W(WWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461*  prstd!\0k:4op>asequ+40[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4920C05r""Ha在ｕR 8$/
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char* i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD4ueH5EUegbpEUCZAAH@JDpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdut0UiwWSIIkSCLAAUCJLpYrunt1et@2d9fS0He22x7fds55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0JuZBwBBiaRU9jhiY2MhETjPPHny5MmT593W3MHPfx7Dhz2zzWnftD3m6a7Huo5xrjsyezBl9zXDLag5QcBQO05/PNQtz60IMaYw5nqa4zFTs/pjra@zGLiqbGbvGaanO2nm6jpr66Z9Af45xiz9gh1YHaMLkJhnn@mW8VZ3wC/P2EPdfDd857GOPRxqVtdlI8ewPPItMPZMA0tv3DljWtv1HK3jGbYFXkXGnlumNmx3NUbBR47OI20yANU5ozjzPiXGntiOq0MKdkd3XRsdy@CoOYb9eOfpp9fCK1n2qQZIjUx9ci15RWEvDN3pXo@hss9P9vevu@bYZ5Jtsf2bKCl5tjP27APvOvwC2@nrlsZUuSyr1z2LQExPN0vZUnbOC/z2DQdKU/NLrTIrGWs8bOsOEN8vwgvDG8gQ4cTmBGe2ZU6ZPgFggGMPgukeM7C0WCGbxZDwf6x3bKs7Aw9OOsABuPpw5E2ZxCzb5wHwsh3mjrSOLnV10xgant5lpgHY2T0fG5dBgbMzfXphO1DwEmdFQsQd6R2jZ2AUPweugMz2UG@P@8wee6MxoOeyruFqbROCtaesq/e0semlWRv8gHjkfjHQLR8lw@pjPl7MXBCCBVWAY7@uAG0M02SAzhmig0m7bAs9LtAdg7Z1wlLvIqi9GbkAkma6Qe7nE55LBuM9c@y@ow2BUbs60eDzg2fM7dgO2OCHYXktWAWmo3lsa4vF954@jLN6SEbZaQshSWvskjEWCzzZuWaOdZcNtSmkbXlQuZhN5RfEECA4i6/FKyyeyzE1y/J5lofKVmJqIcugSpTBALVWzSnwKzK1xPIK8H0hnsZ0eo7WN0ydQ@nbZg8BbSLHqgWmwjubZzmlFE/zEB1KZ5PlSqy4yTYLbBPeZVZWISGEmmdKuQC/IvwAShmwUOCXy/PUQtZAloJssF3W04aGOeXQRyME32EFhW0CREBVAchqCSCUVYQw/0TheQMg7kA7B5CSaZyhyNBDqYElloFPZmMjQ2IL5SNP0h3opompArGATIUS24RUi5DxPKQMtFRLapD5/oCyT3htZuEHOG5CjktA4ixQK4vk2oQf2EEUqSBzVBAwKsgMVQF3Fcw5hArhiuBXhPIq5gPoapdoCxIW4ipITBQqCtIAokEhsBwURZHloYhzWMSFHAM8AYHNIgO5UlJYKc9KmwzIVc4yIL0CyGD5KyDPFEBCQWBQrAqUqwKIKMAwCgBVcgUmROiq5NAf4uYgLpBAyUOcPJihXJQi/iAeFLwCSSqQpqqWZ@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@4g1TBtwyIOghbFpeauDnC51iqjAeqro2tdHgzVE8QoomBBc6kD0X1dokOAUMXRLRfUJVdmBuqVwPB9uwc8Rm086CoQdZZOh/KOOQ@dJnJHFojSyDfDM5MZrDMaMXAHBQfQ2s@WoJG2XxvsLXiaA5eZnbHjTNlkBAVgDCGU17F7PWDat/poACDYsMs60w7USsglMo3QtUkAdUbXshza1nUIY@mQ7d1nX2d9HagNTXoPMCVOn2VgNKIsECk0izf3lgaUwix0RlMiC4AJY/RsW0b3rq27xCOgDoU1HhNz9T7VCKhevZkMGqL6AswJKoUFLAsCx69VCB8TFBZmBpPyC/9T3YIa0wFmhLoOxYcK7Q7rQech0tKjdqh1OvrI89nDJilmWBGN6HAfNSJylXxgsjsQ1u@DMjeHgQBBhYBzIs2/dkbCFXsKpKhpKGL9HgooBJYe6sCMCxRzeiN5CHF@LXXxFYaZw@CVuASHEdUEVA9JNow9lCAoFI3OAEWgh0KGVBSoZM74ZvbBLZq8M2RSL0wbsVFA2ghyJnRCPJbDkOBn3gQkj0yEVZ9zwKBzDreA1tzhAsh2iKTZjbrKGU0GWXgb0KFt2QugAjFDuBhk3ofKgpjxGKWGZobMSNXFnSsjlNOzzjO2X9B0jka2AzWDC50pSjJeZBHusnlHJxE2EUnoeM@3qNBSxLGd9zzeaRuZ0JGiKoY1FZRRDSQFCDHehQCZZ/MUIwhTrSdYPn4XJPE5M0ETalk66rOaM@VAIHvQKkNCU2Y4DojBc2wbeNMTtCEy8Sk0BVq3i5IVyUH1/nriMnL07rhtTK73UzroKL92hXPNYT3sojiga0AlSsR7bjxZJXeKGfESM/bIy1BU/hYhIAWSocgTPej1QEOwD4LmeGp1EuJcFRPTTBx7vZKYBANG5KoZ@6o28q5j9xrckGmGZ1CvyVZlfWi1JQneEroRJuiRkdFDc0C9gEoIKnq53G1r7B1ID4dJk12KjTolfRU5H6alW90wLZ8QiEs0vzJPwnU6ZJAirRrmAINTzqmRmCPgHSlBEUVwyGT89hMdSMnjfqTOcMexReMLLME1kCS7DPV7aAAShIwBOofRMbyWr6XcuxfoK2u1GjAbKFEgNrvJaM8gGIiRQVJDYJmUED8R2bOPPawbiSTkFwNfcWxAWwJOrdXZpTdwoMaR/UqAQEBWwUJODgjrl/NT42zcvV7QFjpiIBFrHehKRscTqwI0/rw21FZRNT5HVeg5xJGqyLwYn0DfYF5yxQIV/WCO7qLWW/NRiZRwAjHweXUhiXhU323G0LvTjumrBNwElZ1Lozagf@Z39UNBlPZ1gqDS3qipHAhWBw6HPds5eVTz6yL3zLQNqzLnYNodzSTndQwuBnEfHzw42jn6emsBDNNoV647ZIx8qYhN7Xgi9a1xJi@rlfUojBngh63VsDHifBhR8L2ZZE8iqtK0A43LJCDn4dFn10kCmhCSg1IAM/6uqTQ8DChdQltzB9caYdZPpSDJMEoQlkkHLIAZGhB19NcCfJ6N377FwruO1Mh3R8zMscYBBI6ZAyuIJ6PnNQUs8Gr3eItIcUELNSwcQJ2ZoiEDfD5Frfk6MqRKR1jm08P9vaMagR1o7plumhIFybge6FKa05WB581xVxcWhQHxB6YOS8kzxFGfJlwXErjTmSPwrGzZEvgAALs4ss0kcxhkzR0A7rvX80auUifkALIThOt6ZVQf6nwsohE8sInrYE93UStKHrPGKnRa2GKFvvPNVqdQ0Dfz5Wiz1Zml2Y0CHZJSbNiB3uiA15kroYs80yJ9tdpH//jxDcRdUiKhKyAFmLkmkykt1xSw9yIZLO5mdqGHZpu6/IIknsjEZCYTD0ZO5Y5Lfc5I@L2J4SWySf5VkhAWUt/ZOVAfBoH9UT4awKBOA3bBsWVyejhT0XGBRyzbtPs224A4XDsMEgS1aWk2d/q2daOENHTErMZw6gPkL47XaCNoa4y31HGkWNHuKp820Sz3AqS0UswhkYhCBCpD4eXX2rkG5Jrl@/jgG3vQiCiFbDY0Z@kBEkTiELnQ1Im4kgOTICHZx2dhBsNpkBu1PfCQIvMQmGlf0IURd2beCx1JYsqZheEXovRV@wbFX9vTa6wFLpy1wBAh2cHTZ48Pnu492fni1FMLhTl7PlsuAuEgvTboQvKA0w1r6wavmpgtBBeDuuFg9QIpMIYOSjCePnYdENwyBpE5Aku4hk8gJb5qD6y4m7yemQv0lV5bHc5CT7Dy8aB@ROhod03sjDh83g3bc@SfgeeN3EomA7V8MG7L0GnNvO7YptbPUDxoGEwzo2DX5eAQxzXcRTEAGXeq8xh8TAtUhykNHGrm0IbOC83loWhgCQ6eBqtMoz@AvjBO@OlOUg45mHKT6UIPAfrKmTBvJIDJBrT1v0E5iZy1v6KoJc7XSlbNZ8Qg2Fz1h7BrPR26TglorYAUyWtWdnrv9B6bgpRGSNeBxJi84c/5YFtgMlAkabAU@/kBcUha4DApygqi0ZsxDuKClMoUsvlNpVjIQLcMummgs0o41CYNNa8zkDxbAniS3aNxgwgX9tyOZvXkDd8QIAt63yeQ1Vzj5emp1QQF/fQe4YYzaY1ps6E0k1V2M8qGHz5ZBe6dyx7ybuAAvEtGYE36siXyrKvdFGddjWpXl2W84chvc6QRe7IDitRbG@R1V4/WPYyQiXpmNubCZjDw@8yCASETowr4QkploEJBSwusl0G8JFB6UT0EzgG5FYnAZqMZPB98/joiR7DTjXxv2HGXBvpRr8FBUncERKQx5g5KaRfHBz1oHUPORykNhYtCml3ocRw@11w@SAmR/FnLID701UIINBgfDkRb4WwtMAHFou45SA7gKxwtHcxGGbHTD5wGCRJOOPgAGoRFkwZ9kDMQmWdkh2eEp0Qu81k6s@wLC6G1dVaS2obHx/jtsYOzgUY3mjcInlN5GIBGmYvIdZo2bOsdPsrKI1MuoBOosaE@tHEoAbQrEgU6ZUHjU47YF3RxoBqqVVbCWReAL7H7uyDFOjofL5KG2IkCltpjcc/J7EjfyGjSW@DmFboVZn4nOgNOhX4SEIBGIsMpcBol8UdASTuxhxToBY23oOeDQN0VRlNvADkGDhO1mj3Sret9Pt4jTCSrNFEbj4PAN6zEZXxtbS1eidfjaTBtg2kLTdtoSoFpm0wSmTCcjCaKkSYT@jYoBro141eNAPIk2UQemKDm8NYYJbRGpZJrprWG4n9V/CahKIDyEFrCD8CJJ2s1NCaTYv0Cp2pAf4/kfRd557jjGCOfBF8FhYDbfRrkiAjQvUdt3tGr2DddTZFhzYFOo44qZsKJnzayp83Ty9Nu6vQqnsbYyapWg/4hCC8vMZT7jj0egeLWyFckkG3JRq7SrLZr8Wx8I5EoSSYkpCWTn5SSKY3TOhHXgacSp6dxIKlPnUZn4BC8SVpNJkNCAR49A3oZppmIy5clSL@dbCZTcYibjKdBLNficaBLB4ngUqZxRIAz0b4xAVJCxYQmLjqnQAKS5qSwun5DHw2mTjRAOOoGWjaOoM9m86EykBSPSsm3PH5UoZvr6Qd6Lw8Hyi0O3qG@NJpy6S5wTE8zcytLgnb3XOoNbU/LfC5Dp0mONJfxtXhGkqAlJB8OibL9xHCxCmuWbo/d6EjjwgFQTB1cTwZjEJbBsps0cJUxEvTOwGbx9fsAnYXTPNiU4IyVxOe9AgDdjgw/FKKoleBkCWgXtB7FALmIa1X4qIxCSHDRE4zNF4qjN3KYWpXisCwmZPQt29ElIAnEEGj1CK01EurMX5JyQCNfN@YlfF9q0rDjbeggEfdNWyPacnEdmQ8aDSPxoX8OUY70rmCC/OiBeJR5WTh6N7Mh0OSs7QyghYDcoCRWw9Ia@h4Z2x11ZW8CUYUENrhRT967A6XzgnVVVS12Cr1K4IdcAcQeQCFhr9SCLm7gJSngmfQLeY8PCwV99KeHD/f42Ak1tti84jhaa2h3x6BX@v2mI93qp9ke8JNh2UMDyBDEf3tmHtm2x3v5YFk2MsM7zcZwbGo05nN9WGZlvI7dtk0aCloVdRZ@7LiaqfFBqMB35/MnoOs/PzmuyZVIoIx2PlyZNo5DLk6W0/MgOudI06zB9JDLGVNcL4jYbgWr2VDM@B5F9Bj7a9mgjAL3TXQPqhTOofjuJXQf4jo20JX9UQSyho5@wDIFxLVtuCTId7xUslfovrQPFoZTKBxXHGfYXioquZ97vd6cc46czyQUTebMOU/OfI3bXB8xilKBB8IFb3NhooCKFCZc93Y9nC@8wiUGA90MZhCPQDHBWTJo201Un6Bvgpo4X3ymgyI9wskQktA4xcY6oGu6N4YtoE6NJB5aiK1RPYE2LIOai7CeYf4Qd5VqimX7U5Mul542dO1p9GSrziessevk8F5bhg@@r7cAxFa9GixFWhYMU4rHw2AElXCDGJRNmra/kdVwEYZLY@oCRakKbgZ6DRM1K51ONveaGZeI0GPi6enkk6z6BXQ@cNHY@r1MX69ickupRXY@Dt0ZgNhgqck8yaAcxlbPNrsSn/SC8me8u4QF4S81CJetkcAHF8MJVqwZuIjFX1kI4jKy2O0G3GtFV78ZILI8LgQEteGSvTtLn79jDWjBzmV3ZBpek13Jnt0aYOa9sWNdX0jHVUrH0aau4K9UqbGdo08/b2SbHIIw1HAiq8RLaxKswwQ9GPQeXO4KJlxv4xkeNey0sMDA/CoyIDWhOQ9AH2DwBKosTMjPEaL@Tn83y0tPh45nQkfM3ekwzfTkldwzNc/TLc5bfDZxObn5tI@fTI2S3/bnECosSxMtoGga6AcoVtnxycO9oyMZONRNxPdwQqYC1U7rDEDfWJbpgJLRzFfYJ904@wTjJLEXLkCVgs5Ey48PzFsF5obuBKSOoqCvOwlwTOJcSgecafqKInKFyycQrprqeESjEFhCT0KeCFhlIf7PLd5z8vGssDhLESWB3Il7FaCtkZTHlvFGdqHdIDUUgsR535PW2NbWEyS@1pUk8Y9jDHEuGLpMpAVCHhoNtgbSjUKLrPaevWxkpXIztc6azSqf4YeIqNPTml1//afm05NPh5GA9HE@8HtlvWurgIMUaOQWY3H8FOBZwedbQNYZt6c3a6m4rorJEFnpLThwT/E6kgtWqXIUg6VNJEJoJdT8iqb59VKRbD2nTva11eWQnQCBMD84DZnguWRrNaYkkwFmHNALzcGuc4U9s13XaJu0/LVnGnwlWNhYV3zC@JACykSTq2LFILphfYZ6hoUxW/PMVxL7lCB/amigJ4U5I4dEkl0iMYmUKlKRvXuHDiJbVxmxgYhLjjl9r4I@LcjHxzYg@9hfQh3VOUho@MtTUHScCmLQeZuf/0Uf3jHInF/TeaVzMRqP65yGdWbTLFJoamVlpYB6Zhh7eGbejNkz3AG95oKGOPCw6jLs3GG7R68FAWgyxZ@mJwcapvc1bChOLXNEHxqxX5Dy/NKUuWTbem9s9WlOE81MenNLSKlcosC9dttYFhSIgKvNgu@CYCArseapcl5WgtqDAzzQLIL85H2iWdavr2pic3SHRsqDWP73P3@zC/S/WToDaK9wPDM0tEBTwJKSeksLy4@KFnotLlg@7D42DY0IQ6bbQHY0B7KkmaFhMWia2pck0DeGOFHhlzjwJr5AF13BZhxzPs8YfBcnsmiqzgK53VkW9toqL54UTSpBd7FLROA6l6FTJBKyvBD0CZ/YiXTcUeDejlSwFIsRM/NyH4y9MX@DOnxrIRoj/K2qm37IbEFrKzp0SLW2oa8ockc7G3dtaXTWD9Xi4oKws9zTzLIEWok/ydxC4@Ls8ww6Rh@a@@C7LNisfc1c0Oc2rnCtsTuS2tS373IbVYThihQck7@XBTH8rU6hYTnVDJNed@REHzowir/GIoMrWKUI0YxrZDa19hRVocHHc1m4XgEkTq2TSmVzSyasR6Pl8bF/SvHL5cWxJ3KH02PRyEOGr5KV@NgcZdhfN3tLqUJzZQw1U1K7EeNSYb5oucONoOFMKcXRz3Ge6Hxhyc2ojw1SZ2xqzsy0gsVneASTE8vGuf1mw6/LHds0XKzQ5jKpGay5m6WF65TpFVlXYSyiZBc6otiOS6FpsRSwOx6uRV3CVneQaXwNKK60jfCJbC8jVse@wN9SDWIAnWH@XtyovV2I1R3kk2R2TA2a8qUtwtyoI45q3sKrF4ar02sxYc8WIup1zIXu87UgGE@Mjg/extmuYdouO6b3KgL1HaACfy/m6SgtDc2SaJQ9al4hhoLFE7MC1cy@bRZL/YwGr6WlPnZ6KPr9712FXCikFOUWIRVoQLal@N@lov0s45zdVkC0eczBhbMR44pWdpGk8id1lucO@gY4I7g4Z/vZEsWUM3wMcUnCOJdzoU2D79@j9VhG2qD1GE1JowYFDyOUS2DwHK5l/31Sy69OrXs3oXQD7OZtmYgU7pmpQ3tF7xtFytSs8pExlGz27iKqZ471sb6wr3HYfq3jPuQV/Yy7I5X1s7HuTwHgrAPueQlDvfU7h3fCGptqtK0UJhr02vXbtZl5oTYCBXyEvednYHiGhpsx@tZ4NFeqcx0062g1yQajoErb3Tns0Odj5VDpFmVpTkV3dfqt7DTxTh6uPKvls9msr8NEpnLmLKs6U7kw7muDv@cSJpdZyrOwOH3nRIyL0yCyRNc2LhVB6rK@PQUulzOWYeneFN93lKZt2zY/pqRAqHYN1MZAuaQ1vKtK7Ia64@9OYbPRCxfHPNq9ZeMWvLXxu5dAH@w3ryr06FzTnUpTwtnUIc50zVtXj@BEZq5uSwX3g@OwEF/Vay7XJf0BEUUuyZsrax3XUO22bmr8MynmV8Ery7mV8OaFhj8LjLPGfK54NscfuyaURlMgltGFjspAH@pkXaHoa93XYzf4LA00sfG3zHui653MZE/vLAswMkAuWPiem5yOKEuebUEXy8MFhNhVMXGJqu@6TAIH04kLiXww1Po6P@RilaScjVngMh3es5sZF49eVPjSnA5Em40wL2cJqFRn@tQNvgsBPpl2oFzHw9tH3K5V/g4Og96hti9bG3uzibUG9sAa6AO@ID20LascwI8eP5RkFeqAdX@Aa@RGo7m181F6mrZp3oWeKBq5oLTt3kKc9nBXLW4J@yi4U60NHv7n1vE7zeOyAw1La81AH0O75NqePdIlsi0LauJYD38vk6HB7PffdxBpZVcfKBJ8/77wb@1b9jXbG43o0xqZY5deFFWizdC36U09vuaFVlvaTl9@aw/bsu8o@wtiaNJ9sYhpG15ngJvQOWfrfbvdGRi3Id3WNc8yzjLBqA@33qnvipQxmPQQnWXTAPI6Uxn5pRb1P8bPwbJC9weQeLMWGlboK4sG6Wi/tzTSzjouHxBFE6vgmHCkNvJd4RXaTl95Mza8GdDIIqlwhJfPTKBhGe7@soylmhVtvpiJYX@5xlIuJSUdFXJJz4LCoywdX5pbQBepYrkcfy1DKJpLwiiy4OVjyO0vKqIBQiMydAvuc/w1txpqYSNnDcZ996bA5CP2XVDR8LV82IIWSUdGraHN0iz/s4zMqpnB3ZPwbYHONdZXTqsUVs6rUDjFlDTbgE8LPlB046VjaKYxcvmbSb2ls3H@Iinoi1@fMuS0mS7uTPsF09V7fBYETbepiEOb5mlBB5E6OKePg@gozLnixQWXZfdBqEsmmwUOwi5TWxauP1pc/GGbKX3xVO9ruIj7seHhKtAFXEEsu2jd0q2wvzbWXONrY8jZMmbDoyD4TKQTPTMAbQvgPdH6RufRXEGESPoE9peQ8s8c@6PTzbK4GBgurqEKDSsGppDlOBMj17Wg37Ag5PWh@/AUjFkF4vsrF4ZeNLxuj6a4DW1KplUj64ZHo6z@d1nXcdnqspVIXIyHo7HrfxbjQKu0oqPQwzNydy8MAC69AdHKBprpLR6pjgy5ghbmN4oz4zJt/BuGaffZN0pZBkobKGGonC9gnAfQPD/DpUGOtYATKe07znziQIfk8Iy9gbLVc0wyLMNbPZrjebhMKPhiZnjLgVsfMo/xLd//WAjSyWKKPL5d15/teb6lfQfOO7bHTkdHY3iQSbRb4Keq7wbLmnGriI0HsVxEe2krZ2@gObStsSc5Y2tlq1Bc2SpU2KRUjLABS3xt78nzZJQbaBn4bVqoDp2/sWtOZ6alawauMZlhgSK2XI7Ohw76Eg/5uUtHtAb5ljg7eDhUh8T1Q3tRf@fZ1NG9O3eYQPiPhw/1Ds4c3pr2U/uJbdnQGo1AUA6PdH6YwNxaj8URMdpj3C4P9OnemswxgV3SCHFtQxvpbShfc2a6S1vEAT/UPG1JU0Rjg9T/C0238ophtnXnNQ36RczLurTzCD3SJ9S3WM4wvA5KXqfDVWIcj5urI3MzNu7Iti3@JmmbhY/yZLVUgaaAXnefK5dxhf/cuMDC/tl8Vg/P@UIRvctPu1iWV0dv2yZ/r1iWZBl8WYDmGLqbeYyHJ5BbMc8k0L7clTJkc6UMmXWNQJM911yap1/c1ZiBVCYfsQpooDkdG2fCfMOKBTqREw9uEdPhpgG@dqANhJ@AxNI6Y//gxtvQMoftIb2WdhgipXmkt3G7UZuOCfG0yc3C5CND/hkJkUVd4ckCgbjCSl1kiWfQG0ne3mzN9aPmqWqM6EWSeul0Oa3XkSxD77zVcNTMJnrNxqbn/CHPmadkXDJWHalGNIqc0WgL/cKaNL96DRQaU5e8gQN9/oy3ang7OL9lwXzIeKjjJPP8LMxS1dV2B5RZe/F8eihcHV3yzw4EWRKeI8j1Q2lnqeaJ4OH/8MFXM9AIt4r54EwTEF23z@AD8mPH8j934cBntuv1jMkh4I37DpaJE8xWAaLAh9cMNG0sywSUnjU2@ehDP7L0atil7phEB@BKkkni2tMl3TqX6IS5yc0c2Xw3WWYHT1L19K7kH7CAMw3S42BjWRjM/y6YQI3KRlzvqWQ4YSfFvL8CdBFxLwLJAPqW7Ukjl76Zkfvs4PHhiTxylYXt084A92Pc0OPmTmxQS9nIkNRrzYnMd/IVaV3D9TIPjhVp9/GBjAGW0JvPaEjwwZm5uc/ScU//3FItoy3tBaGv7i1WEB@dPHmcmu39ZIndgWMP9WTUe/f4OI17W756vNA7GnsfakfPniyNfrCnKMkF7PvcotnBZdJzQUrLIJ3o0BsFZnzED3y5Vbnq2CO9ezId6Z9D44kS3L1j8sWlmXyqnRt9rIWsvJRQVFFZWS7mk5HF2dDZ1p3wu6w8z4wRSssOfTL8s3Q5CmoOuYyTW6w9rJrxv67FsKy/EuHjIinZm9zqGRLUjP4ATRnN/YcipijKMjofaz0oV1ZYWljzARbND5v2@R2mknW/8yKFTpIHXCUZty4l35SGILoz@MLhed8RjO2ly2BWAQidiwsr/IVuTTVLormsVepFBWLjoraVQb6h32FCKlzhc46nSS@c4wtX1bNEh4zJWxI@cSJRdncfHNwW4cin5epQnz59zp5pLp5usjpgFGP9DhjPNKPXEo5b4dF6S6dTuw6AUlfC648W1@cKO9acrm1NJ7dPwtHmVmza6bDiEBbaKJBuGhNjUVvV4eNazxYvM7otbb6Pw57O6cHRU298QB@@888VJZulM43wq2S59ZaSCSo4S6BJm@JBeVGvk4NQNHRQb5HBIbmwN/pYn@ByFD4avKhTv7B9K65o@zaTy5uTVX6lFX75Fend8ENHlpOzygqAhRV@rCCH3o9t82Jgy7uao7t3LJMIaquyVF6RpXJETr8tZXE4lKYYffNyZR/3MfifhXx7ontOfjSw20b@ltzs9PBES/YED2S/tZLhhjJa/NK3/T0h3L4Yh4vxbRLqifZWv4tsOrtdgOqDMe2ouPvCmDZozrrVN/jxj@yB7e2RbWFmntm49H0VdL7B7WhsRY9cdtP@oRl8XyrfKejKwbnYiYSVSiWT8/c2RPdF8h2BeDAf38wHYd@9Y2v@nj3wCLcx@jsF8fwu6EDouL9WIBC4gTNh1WpKocy28faECqgHSUoRneiUpCCtBlu/9DfgVSrKFW5CFCsi8zdIhoee8oM7AS4eOQh5YtKZwtY98FkPtu8xOnqevWPU5QAdRylkwSZnovupq/6@RkBp/fLZwbO945Odk@fHjWzzSkz6u3c5bpYFqQX7uj/JdUXIu082EGX8GF/a/2tCcnQsPnZV3CBfDHJ2LWu1uazNMiVuY5z1S8vKZGgba0a6AvwkkadGvqCXoBOHHeSYysffhVzhuz9NIqm4zkGLlCaUWYVlFyU80qAKrlu@//VbPciX5XLoyxP2T14FluzbdtdP0dXZ7U@Q4v7OwePnR3ssQHDGNBdG1xvUygV@MC8295IO5dQzaEVMjcX9KHEoq1otvh8HwsTlOKvQ5mE6FBf4HIIF1MFtx37sDZZYJ/hAwXhYKJn//M3MVVzGxZ1JCBsPkIozn/IYgJ3ghsA/@0mXHxofHAMSXF/jDKlto@MWBH@z75KtvkhRqpij5ZfY0CHttKs3PB1@djGQQHcGAFde0Ale1053StKBK/xGIv/wrSAhYpDgoGkcJcSDtByXnRu4pZfj0MNzreZZGRcW0FluMtvBG3qA55lGFxcA6mPL42fH@CdNxICP5FCgpNk6IcuvORAjAeNba8DKbR3EHnMt6HrpXoW9Bj7DkbgK31cuSfX4jSgBaH41kzTwhmYk4I2DsNzMqZf58KvfzfSrDMyT7AOw/bJv64H5V7j5ZQbL@uZhWbP0o0jgAXc@1jzxkOZI78hlRBbfvz8jFp7pFUhKZgyhaM6J0hicp8DfEgjYGZxE43MoKGAxKCV/3z5PT3eaCTxhr5LJIBth0y3TWmV9whcOXTtpr1go5pUMICmdBwDpaOw@borkAJPJCjC@cG6Maq/awF5bW0xETV6vFau8NDPr1suc@CpEdB3CChcDRK7BIA5EmcUAv7ofDZqTlJLEqCiP4kocRVHXhnaG/LE9QrvlE0JkCSAWp5GOZy1P8FYqz5kGJ0a28aanyLUJ6z4gSYFWhkxJUfC3mj@1PWCZuU32fKs5LpzjbRoexebyW9fooEbkQflmbZrtkAzuZ/Drl4z1noPKZa83j9GyFV8giGMEUREXsWzjJTv1Tq1mhvMmAzb9kc@yUWa2wPxLmf4SnuX53rl5TF/i@iF7SCx2/9iyscuyD5lhCTWj5jJKMTnLUj6/MEt@jvxkIDt4eMg7SA5EE4iJjm68tkfuzu7ewVcPnx3fOIqOQsavBwNJXt9KnUpyutEMDfFotuaL5MF@5vjJg/2gIGZIFyMSGLQXPyfKqpzMRiIQ5Gxl@/WsLcLweu6WY/yCb3@9jm9OXYUaRbqBh5L9iHRpdam0T3tErieulhZRq1BYhdIMXiYCepdv8LuBaiJ5edVobtVPrVj8JicsqAgvY/IGVgIwnbob6xlk9puZw4yFtyOe4LVMbrQu5hbXRXE9hyci4RZjzz6bnQXlO0Q8IvkNkgERKciZIOjS2nfIte7ZiWUqv72Rn50UPTEmgnAxu4riEVAnwUWQKEVm5y36Rw0ONHdgGm0hOKmHHzkYnIwWnjbIT9lJJAX/1H6ecMK/GnJSmci0lCSRRGlHsNJs1emFAbykABUa9bVnY@ilPbNH/BRnmjJ8qAemIxvE78MxX3ugs6@OhxCuR58jnYZvQXJLEBkoGQ9R5foTSAn/8MJJCo@HhPQaeIShn3F52C0kJkl5oE@6Rh9keyKZBon2iaI0WXjAIWaaDjS04iKV2awUVlbFT3HbZpTsH3XK5WSGgNbQZMPq6pNE/CKerDQhfXSPX7w4jyfFRbxEp236x092rx@7GaK/qayWJJrn187gTMtF0qJcviklwO06YH5eVHCFTLksD1yBbgKroS5@7DmPwQhqRKI31EYsMbb4mVoyI2viNGGl6RAiqc6P5bNYKkVdJPiQh8woZo9MvP1OaNaUJTI1YAJ0da0uft4aI9ZQZLkJZkokydbxaqdd0LjwfJqkAL1aiFIhsDVkIeg4AEa8ksicwSEO@gt4bJBDJ5Mt8KabbmiUy0aaUK5Z/R6L3NA1rzmK5XLFL9B5qVhmwH03xaGcAbA35FygywN1/fMvgGbQoZWF2EyQ35R4MUo3xhF55B@cAejEIkdpBudpMIA1O@iyM3Dwl9izoK7gEUCV5yf7rVIyI7LwAI6@Y3RxFJafBh122vz7O6CaZuaCxqu8j/YpRsOT1Vr8hA88@GufKox4TaTGomS4fuHtjDcVZSXX@xH9UoCQeWwA/F1KrQAcHiEYzIcv8Fss7H/@c7xSV0ysK8pZyzlPxQvZKryUaoEV2Cfrp5K03sjW7q9r0HPy3kxORaZl8hsPz/VBr33Qz5yKIsuxfCazEd/feGaoxZdvJlc5pfTmbKQUG/KbSVMs1dJnzQl79uyL9633SXFyPhVPE9SbZLuH70Qlj53VWKXMLreLudhZGT2C5y3/qMue6710MS6y2OkpXpUrboqZTCPehH/yegUPD9Soy3V5u/n@fbLBNM2bTNlpDK@fZIf30Zv6STTSpKrJY8MwMux05Ha78LMHrMnvUI7xJ5VKSMx3kBrcrTqc9MhtsqP3@@M9bcrdjdgYP/ueH/fJN168eIGGF/Swt0cxHzaHGKRRaWmFGFOz6p/9dO0qffmstfVn3xpm9DX8HOLnu1dP0HysFD5ZW/vkwYN8Pg2k4eZn33j29Z2dnfzDdOFZo7Cdl7JrW3/6J2trqrqlZtaarqs0442zsy9ENZsX5T/7cbz17NnXXLee@z@@@b6u4GsTXudsE@QEPDmmgBHfJfgpqGOdsbfwnPUY/pP5bTdi1tDc7r1lsbcx4HIlNqW/1qyQ15hS3978L98/fBPzYnU188KBrxd7EyuWYtwIBrDlAtt5rB7bwmDFq9g0U6vVwLj5X/4txK9/FeCgz3QLXvVCAKs4jdWlGkV5F6sXwaCoKqT7f33zmxHm4WKiRmpc8NxnDXjE/KYqbjfh2aBnS8Bjz6Rshvre0O4Ff0rpnnKPMcsbeLqNH4N/LB3Pn5aq0Os@aqRSqabckuCRX1LfXVHUUxAAbI61qIYQlXwrd2FRt5BPfBfwexEjngKmIr7iZt@BWI07vLge7sWCp/riH/s5EmLFtfv6w3odRGGuntuop@hZO61UOPkzbLMk2vZ9EBJpFj8V4@wVe@wXTl3MllQxnU7fb1ExIEmlSWxGQMZpxGJzlI2xmY1FnWIsiMZmYT423B4@f/6//vkP/vz79PcD@v0HPCHO6hq9zAbEO4eqU@cPfMW6I16ekgUynK2UKqVM6@o0sQGSqnnElOyn7@KFXPw4ZMrTZDDCGQufeh1f9O/byETfa26@Tz20UIhZlNXhAqLGoAn2F9JJjfN6U0LFqSY1lGKhKXF@DPJYL7PGfSgmUd0si826WlAPoegUkRfcYN1ldgx6kEWItA3PGvzRPzyhdQ1HkdfIbS3woVA3n7Uw3VsfgFlRNtRcpvBJcU8VYo1Gpqk3oSKzegDk/lplrVQpVtRMawVcVr3ppOv6Mzd2riiddrv9ttPW4GlrHU3xtPvyplyS1a2xNtGmmtcetydtrzPuKIoQe99YY0e8GjRZKnhOU7c@z2W55RvJYONPkuxJTIj9Izx1RVXYBgjSLLxAeyAjdO7wD/LBYpfwNN9vNN5vAIfUU1tUPZt1yccSPnLrfjMlXV01wFyt@v9b9dBYpYebIHPNq1Rq62Vdkhov640UgHzpg5Q5TLlVb26RR5iWn5jvvdWM5@140b7PINnUVmOrZu/SD2LCIzUB7tYcrvfvp2Qw3QcA9XVQJJKp1LokraEMb/iyCgI366kgU4gDaDdbW8AAV1tX9avG1tXV1hb8b9H7yv@C69XWjX/6zJ4lYWb@gFG9ftrI1E8zpz7bNcEuZ@roImdOwVCHL4SDZkyIQcXUK0Jsg23ERkzZzMU2hNirD1/@z/g7/fDl72Mbz@BPiGU2sGtQ5j0EeDHricWe8McCM/4CK7qgw5M6Olr8RS4sk3kls4rEj7RXSsWkjGKwZfdauAtVZq@egMwD0cBEtVQUWyllqrLYlljcROHwCzeeeDz@T16p5c0470jjxslX7pMIWj5ijP4g9C8sev7JLyx7hNg7yCpINpfxfAsxIHNMkupCrL41xDV0OGgtYf/g89oX0vMdCTu0mkfTEB3eWasd7NXK5Tofb19/Rnyx8XAD3gr87625Lt4fislc4qv9Bv8ev8W/Nx7@nXTw7@gN/rGTt/h35OEfe9LGv2cu/p28wb@dNv6dDPHvwRv8e@Lh3/M@/gmxGltX1pWsme1klbbSBoPBsg7LDrIDpQsqXEthWZ1lp9kpyw5tpQsmHf6yYDKyPZbts6yVtSAg@ILJY1kPTT349OGvB4Ac@DNwjUZbyXYYJGSiokcXUSF4ML1rnQoN6LGKr3TQwmVFzspFo4nH9zfEplouMRlLUm41Xp3Gm3gurFrOs/ZUXzt9xWIuaPDVWOb0NMPHIpiar@JJ/1dXrdbe04etVgbF2@kT@3D2f3g4jFpX/g8P7SeH9tCG/8PDwydMr6fup6Di379fA0Hgf7Zj9er2aYXESSBSYpmt7dN6TkJzMQVSQkW31Ec@M4jwra@dCvEXiRcvLqqkflUvzqsXVTKEVjC0qmEAPxg3gGPVV9vApRrobxfwnF@QI77QePHiNDRxQ@bFxSl2Q6B/Gf6Dfhu1/lf4N/7f9f/kOUuyRKOZTFxebSXoSeJfMnl5dXnlv@vJRMK3JLbgDx3AjlEur@popECXYGokks3k1RV3g3ciucUB1iGZrTrFnYWD6h8Lk6Rk@SvxX/cLSfvPabzKtNmqgNPTSTabrLaD46pxRkx7R5OzySpdPrTebijNP/0xHUq@naRAhXy1qmwwblHzarWaD2ybpWq1FFjWE4nyzaee3VaKoEzl88lktQqW7QBsFqwh2BKADSwFgKq7WocqfTV2eXBIx3WDjCjE8Dx8LhQSWTrUH@@HiYsV8d69hH/v7PZO8t49tZx99y50GY3ASZlzarW6htNqoXvu3TuxJdIkfbkA9mzp3TslW04p8aTtJJ7ixUKQVEJS2CdqnVIt2w5QYhO8mZJRZ3gMNFfzPCfx1hilRVxq5opJuvcjm7Wd0/jPvvetb53GazVREsk1ryAATIUVtraK@Xq9mAdzsQSkEtcv@RU4/VRZSV6tZ0RODiaux2O@l1LaTHLJGEd/aEfZdh2qt4sPu7yKUbmzfCGZANmaBO3sKoZ/3Fkpl7l7kuWLiVKq7P/V1pKsDgoD/8PecC6V39jcuN9k9DdZ@KBIrl7qNeWqdqlXcFTxqtrx73XE3an6vXu5MtC1lK2eCq3Ww52TnVarJooitojwQkcS7gJeJzVy4g0q80K52cAcNk/j8Ur1PvGHUiowYAQ/nBSHVoKVykQIwejh1nPIvaD4Yw1rgkpffAllfwQCHGPYJPNfFx7WZW3Wx4f1mWEYzGAmPcxk3J/enU4YyOaP7xtaKS4@oYsePkLs2eOd3b2TtLolsZi6v7ObVo@fP4gpaC3M7OSdQ/vR3s7Dw@cQ4dnjvZ3jvU8PPt97/gzcXXYxewJB779n36hpgf2CvRBeO281Xdf0sa63LsbjizfstWG0DCg/cwyZsPsOc/UW4D7SZvmowq9juNrr15ozood9@NF3Pvzov/nwO9/78Dvf@fA7P/jZlz/4Dvx@Ar/v8e/3/k25gO@fffnPf/fDb/8OOP4H@P0R/H76sy9/45v8R/Y/ht9/irj9sf@LhOM/AWD98s@@/P6Pf/blr/wQfv/S//3w5u9Xf7r494NvL/9hvO//7uow3/u38Ps9DisI@73f5m74vRH@t3m4X/nhh1//d/z/T/0/NP7Oh1//Y3z5ln/2wz/9Tx@@9e9VtfSn//rDt7//4dvf@vDt73749j9VP/zGv1ay0dfvfvjBH/zVH/7eX/3h/0D/P6H3793l/8MP/9lf/C9/8b/9xR/6v5/C79@B6ad/8e@hbvztH/wI/7//B3/7Rz/C///pX/3tH/za3/7y/0iG3@SG//tf/hv@/utf/Y9/81vf/auffvNvfu2nf/Obf/BX//uv/J@/8R//@r/9/b/@77@Fjr/507/6o1/@y2995y@//S/@8ltfLnl/Z@X7yzu4f/mP4HJ3PO8C5y75@liXL/9e@PxDqDFLBfgEuPuXPvzGLwKD/zpjH77zE1zKDb8l/z9RFQrzE277/4BBvZln9MmCCX6/9uE730MS/XdAIvgP6fXd0DLnwy3fnVmArL@1INIv/ezLf/FjssX0Sp0GqrG5Lqml1AZ0aTbKZb/J9sewIcovzkMLAfgpfRcl1Jzfd1G2ffjRNz/8@J9@@NFvfvjRL2ODKeXL6Z20pKxeQQktrFS4QzgMWLxLOAz4BaafotEaKfUF2NgXvucXX3whtN5lcM/A/Xfg@gU58YdxL9xT4HsFfuiOmwzYOxY1@8asb1z3XcOUCQtMNUWKxkagBRVybJLyEcL5AfqCOwSabJBxgm9yRe@JgK/Z/8w4EVgKw/AHb1kKjGTw4/lJcKNQgGRSk0lALlLLGFeFNrgLTYlRuvkywxxMJqkJ9HfBACmkwOtBitVqtRRGrHF8wMpRq5cYoZJK1SDfGJvHSbdKCGLygKBAzFrqiLU2ahMeMYXw6gE5UgI6HYmKKqZKtYeQYG3ykCEsBE5gX72q1Uu1SR3Bvef0SE1SDwgnBFZLTervwV4jmBBPiD18D6iUaqlUvYQJYiZ58aRbvJAKlDnKe4ql/DKAL44yb99n7BNRKYktrh0iwXhofKdmobdpvnAb/E9TG3526D8w0m@DCL5GSfmpMO6/TYroNtdNMQDAlSRZlhn8cBJym90H7wkHlaJk4ZPiEFLEEcQBoQPDAZ@UkKLyTZEF0o/VNj76QWCYmfX1dSFWF3PioUyky2SYc1bht@S8432vChOLZRGddVrFHuAC8auU/noc5wbijANmn6T47/79DfYJZJO@MzeBSamcnbdjHMpWKiWqAL9up4SX0AMRgE8J0DtBntRoNiwlpNOMybUY@rHDw0MfCXJ4WRNSwOZqTkE7Tl@Mx@MYxJDltJxO@1@ZvuQg@waZfP2vvI7EpWFMpqr5KnSUqgydWLRXo0APGB3fv38PpUJLSSoH0Dll/qoSNV8iT3DgW6ZNcxrsdlDzZYF3zJlSzDOWoNss4UmypMASbCMp8EXHHIngScTVUilO4YD6cmIjWGRUVIgdcPgyVkdEg4d3FkuFZOC5e8h2D5882Xt6Mmo2maDTTaN6a@TYHd11E@i38/Qh33eglovJWKOBoE8qKgoYYa@SJfF38PDo4LjCeKb9IkgQYlWaGvKzWVaE2Gj0YivmL7IQ8VobWzzGd2WWt4RazkHUWF2IdXTsUQAv4T/8qsITt//AnkCfPy2KaaWI3bgkDdoy4ev2mOGJa3x7NtQpXIYub20RBYT6pUQD52iE0ioK9bq/PIkpQv147wQinBwyRc3KQv0LNpExQelKqJs1U7f63mAd1/mIp1kxkqf1RjaNf2ouB28lX0wrhc3m2pp5KWGap1Rsl7hg6wqslxJm4yvwMOErAvsKOMEDaeAqLOYvgTs4rPrrkPBskwRfjCQqBahmSeEUCpqDE0bRpzoC9oZefeQnxNa@8Q2P1evQl5YO9oUYiIsBC9biSEZXHshUzt2xo5Nvn7Gu8bmBFxbJXcMdmdoU6g6QI3Z1ddUDSAf7TK2rZOUxuvi@6pBLG8xXE02IWZVK7b2S3xTyaqXyPqeqAjgIsZcvNa1eb2Sbl/lNNV/IF9RcsVjYVIFo5XyxUMpllWwxW1BVpZzPl0vlzSuWgJLVNKley6k54f9/7vTQhMXWqA7k3MqMwKiBMb@V0cDYBmNhK9MGowHG8lbGAOO4nlOyW5lxXWDCFj9ejOHu5Zro6RM8zZC7iXVXN3sy7l2oiZSAKm75x3XW/Xh13ARia90abnHFxfuJ5KXQrXXtDl21JnTltt2dyq43NXGRv2k7tTioVvHAw8Dba3HjX63BmvLIHkETqBY2Uw0lC4IYf0opraa7csfUNWe7UCmU0BJOw2wXspULw@raF/IXTx4/8rzRkU77CLbz5UpXxjNEcLf/dqlSKDQbDVFMNSiZJt7cyGu5tLYGNUPXuhJ8e7bluZJaakLkruHUavH4dk5RJaWSy5aEqzD7AhAO81QXMGYK85JG4l361ahi2RZU2UpaSxuXlO9Kr9e72rhMzSyCdilxG1DkStLS7cvQWpUi4SpsnJaMmSe4aD1oUS79OaiKqBZKYrVRndk3i2K1eSXcH@pdQ8PdA6fZy5uxiiDaONQYJHTKhKuKY9tepa33bEefBcwpxSAgR@hmgLx4FSZ3msUUL28mV8RAQENOOeBUfphbnVbMNUAMNPegHWw0t4Jj3pBDVVVSc1JOkZQc/t9iUPH/7uFV@FfxDbFyqnCCW52fglCGhsRij3Gzo2ezE9umCwQf6J0lIXYHGi0N3HVs1/0HhHmgWWfc66HBzxcLvR5peHOIOzS8wZIQz0dD3HepO/9oEPaGbUCQKjYFeAAvx7TtRQE22fNnS3L5JDzRE4jBj/SE4EcHnz46iXxP9nZ2HwlF9uDw6cNrn4IfqMAe7@2fhNZN7htELYQgvr73@PF1q//JHz4/6o1tB3/C/uHz/OwVOuFuMyEPz3yg0JmA@C@0ktqCQ9RrrLAZGBQB1yvfg67XPd9YKM6MWTS@4FvpDDdcP8v3TFaEk2B/ncZQALV11uHba7EvSAfV@JqislkWhBGz7Au2mWVd2zQ1vJC1twaOAw33DemoLpl0bzAmfWE7ZvfC6OprwhPcolRW8NZJREJ4BECG4w6dCmF4Ah571sWrUnFSpG2OdTbG64iXOMIHndDoGP0BNDAXdhBAaGsaoxUyH/dAfD36eKsdPJ4Gud3wMW8GF2KC5mmxUvXePeWZAzWlnq1U@np9bwJsyp5DtdGcabpUEOWOuM/kVqxvNNzmCEoqly8qG6hpgXq7dpo9q@TtUV1zoSVK5bMN0A69XqcKDVyhAiSul6BtUrO72YIjio@0v/6tn/zdn/zaESutZ0DYbeArpogiLpReUwSZ1Gi1XCqUyjm1lC6VS/mCUiwU0oqahh7IZhmU0KxSUoqlQllJl/LlHHBgGXwL5U0hxlehZTYIJHwrANbq4L2IW6SJywNQufm0GHub0JIspoX2MRN1iCMK2OnxaCfmBjNq0NYwJctymwxAaqzDYvv7u9n9fVF8gBZcCLCbFcUuWgqlbHbzgSjq5LNbQg1CtHmcEp4vI3rcks0@2BXFMQeAR7OK4gAte0UctxFFAy27O/v7mE4PLSrGh2Bn3IdbzMCyCcEstORyHMCbEBoE2@Hp5AnRPbRgkuizz312wU8UPw3QQZ8jHowDeBTkdGdHFA@4ZWcHfXYp2wWO6Gdo2aFHFB2wQG0QxT4Y@g7UQ1FsgxHrhCh2wNSZauCGl1Di6Z2Wp4nilJMHCSSKEwqtdc5EsRW4YzKf@9gUkLoVsig81/fJUsY/UVQDpDFYLrTkRDEfWvKQt0ePPtcGXlfv82fq8G8HcvroUU4zJuO9/fann7b7/bYz3dn79Ai9dncfQXM/HTvtftuP2G7BY0Os3UeqdjacXn8g1wetVkUzF3p91mrlNeuaV2va0hFDiPUGMPOfPiY0bO2C1@6j1n1t0RQlAWyhOBjCt43PgyF8H2ht7hU85EXfSbstVpH/UTWmG6qhKtJl0emh1nHsKtontTXG4ol4etooZptV8mBDUIKz1Su6mjqBbw3HGZKX08aklm3WJrVNla9u6SXE04laMMT02nBbKRcqa9q2ouZTkwpu87Z7cRaXlG2WUO5tvGWJp8ltNZeviKfb25LYUJrbqlKqFDdfboxFMVnB93ZuswIBs3HopOMr2dhsbm8WIlE2N1NaRq1sbiarV0APD9r3Nvb/W4nEha6dJZOILvZGIQv8Yuwp5dOo9hKT9KTG8WLTZHVSU6r8wDqWvQGri6ejjjue7XCIfQA32c5W6OptUSmXREg/k0kkkyDwSDbBd7bU7cXXTs5OTr4AUQhdd7@X/Izf51r1rZ8@2pWh4@zb8FRTeR@7ILYj76K8mvPhh24GTiegp8uPoEGFXkrghltvHNuU9yYdfYT9mMAjOKtO9k8Yk08ezcE5HkDXY9/v/LhVOvjC6ugMD301ukyr1cGkdVmCsGJa8oKa8la9XmvVhvz27HoY6zNGJ6LOwBy4HPdwPzVFv8TtKL5Hq5a9qrZrk9gE4LRqTFJeDe3uKzXVqXbxrNcHtQcYudqCb7uq13S8Q1yMidXetlVjbGy5Wk9/pjt4OsDB4TooFrhHJdFjenKdndKN47uozV9JdYdZM8yejocJ6Km3k/NOESuSJvG1IMuXtGkKp/2vqr0aS7xMVt@A1Vlnia78ILmdr3YTD1grCS7ZV71XPaayYr5KlzAmEBJUIqIN3eSdrNU/A12IAz6rVAARv4zPACamBGCNLnloyZFxVe3UTJaQ2IQliTz5ar/WwNjv8LUliWJTkhrvmkJdkl4Idain1WlMq7njNh0QzrJtRc0WqxNwUzbz1QEUrPZyUnVqo7GjV02w@kNGfG@YVgVyAtUAzNt3iQ@/@M3kllSocbcqgXpngvrRklu1SdXCI4eAJWq5GnikGvlsGnq58NpMQzuvFtNKMZ1L59PSJrpCI58upMERejqgWSTMhMiYmM5OsrKSVnQlnci@MrqvkumzBKgvRDKWTHv2Hl5gDi5QSMiVZIWvxpIpdcNkUAo207YkYlOQFFXMGNB8wEZGeoCgjnTNpBjJpMRyGwlzPYFh1k/Go71Gs1LZm4y@Bl4J6c12MbWZTb1NJquJtWQN1CChXhXqKFUo16M14Fl/NI2542EDyhhMyqZaaTTamMXNbDqXzUHujNa7/pZYF5vp7FpRgSK6YqQfMS4xuI4003Jmbi1UwE0dSk4pq1VBpgUilKSSUMtqUsA1iH5MYeSLNaQkS5yKwT7IRDy@qcbjyXgVx7rXRH9wE2QZybE4CNX4PWVbBAVMrIhlFQPMRCJtdctGdbArAUcHWL4sxC6Fq8urLejeZmhJICiTbI1Mkly/L8QqjIEieOofppJZY@xjVxqmtuov@fcUly4DXIEOBwQtlFYA6Qb2ydjnuK13m8UBMc0ZNlQ112yom9CSgXQMgqqqUsXx/RgujpbrQGL3EvDbStVxR8xnbDrVUlIw4HyPsX5qXaBMx67P4e3UdvpHO9XAtotDmKeCKIrVuBi7jMfiV/AnxO7TNhyVb8NhschGHBzDxjFioM/7GMkGtnsZDD1V8IqahFbhkqDRTL5/apiXpZzExxdANF1dxUDLxhLxdzNUP3ulFqCMLDvY3gB9IhzHgUaqUMDx11jm1cj9hlrKPTk4tB46@zrjmxtK@ZZYj7GsIuFmgWrFdy3wZc1iuaSK6lk6xu7HqjF2JsWVCm2AGB2XX26@LL188vzw@eG@EDtde7dm48g6C6jC3ltf/Rr0JeK5fJyx01psUstX/TVf9bqkbKl4StEmq4BU7ylFKfuuzrm3Th5FFXw@/OIP85OtEtjVrAJ2VS2k1Hpd2VBZMjb68OXv4/EUl3uf7zxmcVebsr/7kx@rm3/3J/@K1lHFr6oujQNvxiAkGpXiZuzycnR5eQUP9yvEmjGOVH4zCWY@X6DE6hlFzVmWVWWVjKZtbKby6n2rmvHDKptKMuZKMX/mY7MQc9/5Xmq2BF7B1AQ5iUUsgdjekVFQlftbyBNKuDWLhX9bulsGpig9efWOMbB06t1@31DJlMmwynuJbb2Xtth7nA14L62xV7U6ziYruKErGCzfwI0rOGMUr6cyG3EGnRxWb1xVmylGw@3QP3yp6xvW6TWOPl3DRfPzThsW/OkbLv1hpMDBBWtg0zdeu2JiI5nJdLv@YUZbOivUgRU2MoDZafLDL/6Gqhb/7k9@9V3rXesLFTqB5XJRUWM/V37@cwiw4lCBoAdHswq4@x8NYc@PLbm9HHq1QgyvtO8xHj7oB2LPD/UEo29Bbx5twjnqNlRKLX5SVTcx5h1E0PvSpCnTOTLJqiCEGiVpwk6/kyYYbANvloBaKlwKX0EvaEBZDQSn8JUZKHAYQpNpd1quOXZGtI8gQfGUZprdgyiQwlfwELA12ivtS18JBFZm42ZUjrJLVCM9iA1118UjxaDhEL4CUfxTAPHCbA239WNIwwJxL2MQwpM8ug1IuwlpmzxCi1wTlHseIM04djySBdqy8BVQAIgKBugFzNiCAFUQMV8BAkAeEj5go8m2WC7JLo1Uqjo7r@wKF2jj2WpasKVYwGgIrYtb2IPIVQwHTqCl471TyBd@CYNKFnEMgHAYfI63Bno@RicbKlq05//OoAAWna@ToKyxe/dmWNVqRjfJKEcI/8wY4ZgVlYO1GFcAFvSRPulWxDTDk@CqgWvIdkDxFKELXCfxI@CqkahMROuVIMD/nZkWOfJaUZFHFTPglxevFR0gGURGsvMy7LCtGlPUzSQLke8A7h1Cik4fCzt@p5NPZPWLwPMKMPx5LDjVHQTRSXQc0Ofb63vKGTSAYzxSG08W4sLA3wvOzw5CgXbgBbHDWJAVw6TQPcOBTglNPgcHkSVyShKjzQ5uIzxo2bWaZ7j6uZDED8XC0Ay@Gh655aezRseGdGwoUHdkW3RGF50ngivLgSNARvlHHXG0x9YFXsHglw1FjmLk0jFHyPmIMZ05RndXUlyc/W070HMNaJNmel9mnWGXqWWWIEajI5msEFySIhHCbdBwkcZtUx8CSse6Tjt@3Eom0wf9aNymc6meGMBXg30DWhXLzfjXhGYujDMjc4JHSEt2DzcG8V3@MVSpsPrxiWb/DCjTts@YaZzpfHg3MXdGgstAxwc9NQ2Unf2AsBVcwaDm0iwL3mkeCn6b8NnkxlI6EnctMU3e/OaUtUQLS/QdNTKGg1eAnmtWhL70vBP8bq07dYNTVuisELDLocjV/fMVanHcOR0eHCL458XU6KgSGacNRgnoZAbnrKAR1G/9nGEHVcA2BoRmJzixAGsx5PYr1ABQ3YOahUeueU4Fz9kATJxuogNVzxfwFvuE5VQBA/JDcPwDawAGFn1tHjr4QVTMh@t1oWBkvkMN5ArUzmEX/HCHt89@GD/gbjTTcXgz9mZrPjhsdCitGuPVIrAUIhasHcjPlPU18CwChgswWUuIKQCbEpMiBx3Gvx6dc7tAsqTCbkJKM4TgkxqgkKoQ3BHMInclCODxQHP5EZ3@4WwXFxcynRI4dgxZd/H@ABcvPs6M@gZox3bG04cj/6Y2A2/o9OHOTBK/NgSvw96e0EXU5XtT/hWEnlvz14Ek4j03jo3jOR6P3x/S6UJ4rI9LDLVv0NUanYS/LIXzn9pMXwb8V0H@k0rxKwTCGIKZpKfpThqApduds3Tvolv1Pc6pQgJwKEU9cMSTOZ3AMnQDkzHqhSFsj7ZxBPa2eUZToABJ5MOws6R5DoOQ08Dq20fGBCJZ@gXbcRxtmiD/JIZGBk5MSe1hU2j2yQeM0MywS35MpDFpTJtz0SdhdGjUgs4Pc/DoIOFyNVB@Zij6T7j/BPwn3H8ySzRItjFpcpUMna4wO8j1eOJcEBLBTIMwV/x8zZkPQQYdmykcBIaczrldwa9To9gBvbkNyrEWMAbwxAgIricyjZenjdOm5eoXG81Upg/MLhIhoMQBdKNJNL3ohmakvnlujmx3zsnCgwahVfLxRqfOwOcGziuYx7CAiDE4vQw8G64/9JcOcIXAzzBAQD0MPFE12PESRrIanlFLnsA4DXFGY45Yw0emSdqX7@W7gbrESc8JGwXUjABC9zBLgCb4sKDm8NtiAunwwrEhTBBWogsuhnhGUbwZB0peqypc1lSpkCJYSVKAJpAd1dXa9awE/lAUjWtekWxe@eUfRX/to9HvQb1YjD0xLG8wqkK0quCiN1Ah/OpCVGX1WqRcAYPMhmbqDrRce1w/9VtrSGYjE3QzeDqYBfcCr8BNRAq/k@TlQzvrREushKwwrdUgi9Mar5a8XgQk5QQPo7l@tGnACH58LkAARnZhNN2PNolGm9RqXHCwyZJoFxEkJ4TkhEfhoSdLkGz60aD3FN6djsXTBO0UV@WJAE/hzSioQSOR4T24OJP9Gs9PwwlPP82ZzCEu8HkIVWzks05zYeqNCNIRoXUNADLiDQBdfvFcRbgu8BQptIUyipMykFHc5rMBlxXAYCSCq/yM0UTIZNQHBoVfTFE7AHVXTDUEUaGxXPzL8p@YDhyDn3LTMTsfUpl3zKav/f2jODaRspEKGtE@lGweBTL2ZJ5b/uF8UZ0jhne0DmzQ6toXNkssULbBPTP2o2bapt3ODDVckYLXUflXNI@myaD/gPMg7P7I9jTPzucrvNNkENstSp/3GYy@ZeMp9pGzhUHX69q6a8U9KNSO3bcMV08zPALuTPe7Hbp/lLkQ1ZN9o@0Kgj8aybuxCJrzFaq6rRZekNlqJXA9XbISrs6l5XXInvG4gP1fMEXig3jygR6OEnb7td7xkrfDxGOw/WgnRucscTjyPeOQyA4DGdYB/R98B6DBMNee9RzpQF5Updtegq63GNhDuw9a39iVBYx9DfzBDDYipI1GhEuaadilrUQOQ6dakuiktaQf9bOPjso@UxNaMoyvzgOYI0aaOddpjJR1FiTXWpocjxakd/zx@B5H8T1ejS/1wq/jzLvmNe75cUnnEjMIEHCGRu52NDDrILe6N9CZQyV0Rr2KR7gzil1a8dVFTHcg6I4fXO4Bf6RDmwu2EPHPl9F/dQEG0ffuWnwa3hp8PAV5M8SFiAm6ysANJjQTEPwgmRRiC5ILWfvhHdOCsHjn0z6qEKDGkuCy8CxRqJgj6Ha74Qn3AeBbeB4XWd3ge1p5VeOeC3ByztPsTF1eRA9bXd3Upno34YdMR@AGOT6CDhvJq7tlHAUdCT2b9/US0HYlQ19oxpHoPFBlCcto6fNkcjlb8SBGyD00Uk4YHiynH/rfEM04xFfjo9XQD4jHYzgce27g8OdoOpry46pNfl@ML0d5@8NLEo8PuJ0gQAf/xJz0LNnkKvF5lAizdIcWIQwrz2cZT5MNIOK5NjfL8ONIdHtOoXAjkWpBKQvzVy8sLnFjVYlHuCLgST6FdDeWvI3p7sxzEVbjwGYibPfjmpAbkHENRqeTiELkLitLzLZuyAR0o3E6a0mr0logUMOYJOk8g7rbpF8kBewZH8AXB5w@hy8C7OteizNUkDcc0/KvhmHkM9RGEa3FdwElHaBEqMhJ7qMRCSUEZgh@eRWm2VmaZudGmp25NMMaMJ9kJJDQmUvSLwUsnlVFYOo9b4l0Ri/sO8NnldiGx7I1B0crLuNGvGKkWfw8XgGBHNfjlb0ECOV4N155SAY3Xjkmw1m88hkYZnUr/i5eCaoFBnDASob76O6LcLR34pXdRPJK8LQz3Q3SleOVsEwhzDa3EkWAFJhv0Bpxis2y/Wx6jg4NGymVaYYc46ax@0TjMGn6ZeGfX6ZClzKgJ45xblBglmLKXKMRaTF4OtBsBId@L6jJFb813zvcpzVMYRBMJgV9vGgcAg9qeCw@L4w4YuhLMxrwBQRRblYWY8QiLdkd0fFTBw6lQp5Pn6gnkz7QTZB/AwI3Z4nQDTp@/KC85kHwArwbnhh5GZ430AmSI4xwTja5AC0k6qv4ikxhWc/j4pd@tIRorHs@EF67HQThpURgIzIddDianMPERvZonknIF9fNG9E4NCjHKyVy77VoJBX8mrnEm5z9nKFgiFb@5KrsROIhanMiCD0b2SavZWG7QLIYvWayLqKp8soHKERkDtRwvXNGtxM99I0UjoubNLUVy5qhIC5PkiTXvJiEyDKegzTWPJ562Hndw9ORPq77GsSc4FhLAgFEYoapcPlqf4T@bnP9PVCoAyJcS2CRYr24Kb2pXq9sZa9hbs6SvVmA6JlmD5MLlaMwhRnJoXcQ0cxX8doNFR@XfHAlnycaQr@m7QdkC/sEt9Dtet@Cw0ItwTmfdzxTwfFMXU6omxqJeS4HSouMKflweMZDTGdZW40rz/iiIkYfGt/WzI8uYGe@gKOFh/AoA841kvNa7owtWuUyq9sgtrkLilSlwrggp@nSsJhnjiDuaeo2nLYFh8PW0cPDp4@/Do3u5uZm0m@jpzP8sNbiWGvYjnPItCA6bA8WdFvUNF44gpPdOBxPV9yvnVriDVnChTUoAxqkErCfX8eTviyLyPNrdRfi8bARivqwzmbVQJuTSqjqaNhkGz5dPSCI7iU2NB9IoN4CvdPUW0vS1RqtFl5r3mpR89Vq4eKlVstvxbBoghnx5M9ja5mx69BVj/xemAtBoHMH2MND9uLRzgk7ebTH9p/vfsa@fvicvdh5eoJbzp89f/D4YJfBb@/p8R4T5hZK4h1a2KEEuj7UOzpedYiHyOUZQd61R1MudxK7Se5@rA3ZI7uj4zTVlqsN7w@4RbZ0r85j7UF3dIpjmAbdkzY0PFxvQZd8QTcWlZsu7fXD9fsMwrahTzvEPu/Q7ho9A8IK2PcdGbobbA9jpgElCPI22Oub5koS3udFS4fo5j1cgXUB0TUIj3M3AEbj66/o5njD5RH0rsx8woXPR1PwZO/oyTHD0wt2D58@PDg5OHx6zPYPj8D67OsHTz8Feh4cnxwdPHiOXhTwyeHDg/2D3R1y4AhkZYbHCrweu95KFGQMTlTpnOHMtzyC4g9t86PeqMGzC412PbosPrZQ@hiaabzVu/GqMHZRfcGdljRVwBLrO0effg5tPtPf4AxnMBVM6w/E5y7dK7eeZVuUGlSWOtS3ql9dodmTlCTNRwynDK@Z0Kt03ECCzGkWAKdFPF1DZ@IurlHBsW9@KgHV5QA0JLQGsBFUsGClxuh6mHg8vUUg65Bax7TxBEmeGl9E6Fsw6v1gqUlVIIr5a2UQKO5ROLBwPEiphg7A9@Cg@sl6Dg/AcqEDD8Dy3AFV0QNcO8IKfoixdzhG8cyK3OH1cLRP08JsM3R4oFEvtuTjxMuNilRj4fVaeEaDSZcA8VEeupxQczuGQVFcCo8X5Jgmrxg6v5oNZCKfSqS1bRBSBGHTw6kGf9kbv8MUfYEbcJ2Q1vNclqglZXaCi4N0y@DXL/VNzfp/invarTZ2JH/TTyFsErqh3bZJIARjEgMm8SyBDIbk5hjiGLtteq6xfd0G7ATumd0f@wK7//cR9lXmHebXPsVsfUhqddsQMplzbs4J7m5JpVKpVJJKVSU2gYpMd4j3xDqGwyluyeWDvraIvD4GfWJAvDItjocutytXhf5jy0HJ7akaG9JGkq4OVCZo30NgewqBfwYMAMrEdjpNmqnIERXB9NuSle2wDxyJetvfzfzAzq2rph8rIK227L8EX786kshubJ@k7BQJO@iir/4QlpV0lNnuD2GMk1ili15QCjYv@oNRwH1ox1tAJ040zUFunNigti@KuLI2pEOyxl6/Z1R6Dlx8T63nwJSPqZU4ns/OtfiKbv0EzodJmO3uEJ3Gef/aN87OXDxEuvFR/QILYTorR@XnZESY8PrTimTH7wIvDlwvbu1un2Z@/@Li7YEsFvjCTmV0iP@BMbEuGB50zkcGi0Ncd8mRpm59Cq/OsbS0wZPSEke5Agb7wIsA9nWv6wWdxubG09/RLyb5nT7e3ha5VAYlk7zDNbywI@nmipqq0qUyZ0KagBiyE5AFWW@rLy7B1PL6NfrCYC8UgCI9lCO4b0/cqSRFiGrd@VUbJIu82lJ2t4bviC2yqIhu@kUfF7M/sp/t7eLylpONDEqEQU5biWhXQc47jmGWQvPVFLjdh8GB/H48uPUHsePp4Yeg7T4I7YdwyyzfD4unJQPW48H@/gBYntz@KbDQdvd@wDxJTkPTnK6Z011Ia2vah2v8MtV3NPYADM69qEHRQI3arnp0RK0CNttcwDHBRAui6vFu@ehIpHh/AmVB7uGWoSXFIMKeF@8ja9ugR8LO04smvVnWiyf1JWbRpv49NJhnEu8eUSHXIK6khxYW0Z3W7WDMUk/OLLSEIOt7EoiKcnHsvikZFNYk4DvYAwKyUacZDbRmNjPNk08Qmkbgkm4ur41NG36ysOa5Gy@MHE5MQKZNUKODniWz@@8jr483VD28wMJoPtjgFqykYb6BfUIVKh5ARs@L9@AD3aK6FI3seYGdVrRDw69cfIX98wxFjMSLcF4LG2JdLo4larw@XlDLHDJIxGmggZaeMpEtmiFBiXj6sml2qBNNenZ8CoJFJl4h@NrkCih@dlfQl9rb0TxZ1Atyc6wtEDY1heUZamcl7ML9mZ6gLfRaUjwkqwJp@2BVmX9NVTxLxGpSNJ/ZGJUIkNdWV599D3ayFap45mdh8xySlJ@jywHs7yOQ4SQk9T5wbuXAVekRAzxAOjatVwMmURCWOjPmlFjbaTIy8QNcWC8EyGD0cryVMVmrI8YJ3GZD5xnJhE5ZptpgDGHdUB41U9S/e7g6FMjfrW/@x@vjwYaZ0HTwDq3y3/WHoR955RkBWYxP6Mka/@YPhz3Kxv5MlwjFJjemB53tyNuODV65VZhI521mS9rSO4nNbl2la6BKSL3o4UWsqN0rJNV7mXzBbOpeZb8sliiqYTumi0wNU44he@aD3kMIkAwmvQROH@TD9yTcgP@Ag6tAApnIm88m2jjfxY0oAqvmGt1bI81CpWzNJ3u/HTYbPQzj4aaehCLlPoWCpIUtH@45szTruUKsPCAXDno2lHJTGS9FReEbKnQRUhwE9yZ@NyYs9NRQlpLoXtPpo30UHmz5Y9aekeVkI5tfz629tKh1PXfkXtZenrlLzWJKwOTb6F2GV8Ob1q@d/sV1W3TF4C/n4@bk629CrD4Xz/DezaccWja/VsxSNM8X8HddvMwR50oEX1GY3NOUEB5f2SfEooj24YV5wdfV0aZ5Az0kElwqli4VF6KL3ah4WVs7K/aKucJlrXdWQCe/0XJxtJxftvHDU5hFQcbwyXxtdIZzqql19XvXAm9ypRv3pGuIINcQ@PKuMQz6@6WDNzFtHC4AUAUmbb1Joc6XsM6hNRv6nng9/8aWajJXIMdauECy5sgrKI/e7aRPRnVMKwDMoFdcWM2GY/o7cay5nHc1GPUpRcUZRNYSt8GtNafcmHKkUYAstUBFI6S758NxlMfGgyH@OmEr6kyel2t59J10DBA1LEniMHWaSqFPISIqfblqZ1bo@Y3mBSKBtw7fUjGxuUl3EAOrhR5p8dCUozEkh4ncGT7iAQj8DOi0AauglXtIbh8WNB/f8/jAX0hHNSI/GTKQt2iliClo/i2@kX8Tld8EAjDh53jN5UkVp1x5wUKSfQdJuYDRyuIbfzxmQLdK7pQ5bCzC5vqKEXCyFCcaYbWSTPB97gbJybSCf7IFmTy9TTVD53c4O5GEzqnlW4i0pC6lpC386UbFbKNYRhVTmQ1SzH2XGqjpgu3ROx@G1UTs@N0uIM20mIvIgY/k3yvrX9b1hzWs80wjz@mZqfRMLN3jdEYqyuXBBB9l2jAzpdLfonx3IhVlc6fqKgpavHjQ000PliRR3sJDeUNv1K8HUeYt3ZXMlTphM5aQMVI@z@h9TpmPldEMrtNrnC75e0X2vMYylvd1vH78tWQH@WQ8K21NElzq9YLuK0teWCtTkM1SQE0huDj2N7EdD0rpgynFCazgUM9Pw3arGEFZziuJQ2MmtbX5OuXJRcYrO4kGezFODawZY8SgEtW5TIQbk8Mi1EPJ8wYIgomMJtTI3VKFJ7LwxACLueZVtewFOTXAoWnJIV5Ev8hb/KMGexw5lS89O3GOMR9z49m7OU4gErrzqdlkiksTdBfhj7JRD8wiUd2TJMTZQuLA0ALrOn32wW6jGnxeywlTUChJMUV3nSIpHWXIK/a9rwsx8c76R3bJetOANfag649FCbcZDfLCsmIO7iM/HIUYz4mi0oRXg0EXTx1pwXdDLtQyZsjKKh63RBCNmd2zKmjZw/ldfJIO6VDIE4cI@QYNRKKE8KrTQWcy9IDt36BoRY1LMPKsUm/CCg0YM89W2M3cF1chn5rCbr9jIsE9x6MHKR0OGk3fs2CNFsLqx@KmtgN5ayTp09FvBCOGwZS2YVl/vgqav@68wfPcF/ncs7xBsmt5HJzznj2PHKyASCphBaP9reafW5ZxNtzks@EMAnTFPk70H4A3/Wu/1/OtEswYlDGERWvoD6/9lmdZR74@BEa4yMp4Mol@2P2rYZOVO7DoagAzopdw6PJxGHAY/uL8zMfFTTorcy08tIpOm6Grr4MWElB5nLT7eDpMBxYYJoDpgYUu/REQZckRcZTo7FniQmuXS1REATUwzolxNqHJ0OuPgib0DGmyrC6A4mOQqLJeK4EJ1NfsNtA52JuFALrHRBRQCKijpIdwsOSh@Q/hIGTD1Bl7Q/VMFqRfn8YKDHd/GID0jQhMvULFDNyhg4/fVqqierh3/LF0VBbw/P7o8ENlt7wrtj/RGTcelFMoXfH2cB@kiz5N51PzQ/iQKlWhZIoSrNLBJ1H@5f1RuVoVh0ei8u79fgWgAfij0sFxpVx1ReVgZ/9kl07fAYI4ODwW@5V3lWPIdnzoUq2qmBWVE4d74l35aOctvJa2K/uV409U417l@AArw1P9knhfOjqu7Jzsl47E@5Oj94fVssCGWbuV6s5@qfKuvOtB/VCnKH8oHxyL6tvS/n6ioYcfD8pHgowEjFZulwHL0jZsYbEmaudu5ai8c4wNip52gHiA4L4rqu/LOxV8KP9ShuaUjj65Emi1/OcTyASJYrf0rvQGGmfZ36EK9MvOyVEZQyEhJaon29XjyvHJcVm8OTzcJVpXy0cfKjvlakFY@4dVIthJtewKvFyPqgYYQC1Ih@ftk2qF6FY5OIY54@Q92js40MkfgTCAZQmK7hKB0QwCWwtEOjz6hFCRDtQBrvj4tgzfj5CmRK0SUgEtKnaOzWxQIRDx2GymOCi/2a@8KR/slDH5EMF8rFTLDnRYpYoZKmiQ8QlYByo9oVZjPwFe/AjMainOdak7RWVPlHY/VBBzmRs4oFqR3EJk23krae5hYF1DiRL0UWfQuDQVK@3pT9c@BpSc1sjM1tHoiEk7h7tlmJFl3KpUlHACs856IpSSmQYzjU6E11jImpZ/ftWpB712H31MdTFWfFyGHRfvkXHwEo5T64FrlKR@hQqk0/X6h1IdNrrVet1xH1Myhsb3Skg1@EO5HNlGvEMAd96o@NnYYLpvxgi19VQedJKhHh5AYE6m/lM2fWtc@o7IZlu@LIbO@whYqY5CPja5wKMUEI3k7Ii3h0RVkmaC3gPJDlTQVuC9Zh31pGgZSZn6Ifzp3UYvPDkYH0A6s7orm8VNLKERfPVVNVwJhUSgPzIiQdCmKr3Q93/t2DmzOtzze51@v2U7jipDeUewD@zYzneKn/udRPFMsjwhS8fOMnR/qPbdtITR58@SZEL2izekltn4pz6iH0dhwzEfUGtKVZGyWiot7adcHC2SXCFDW6B7BXUyrvnelX6pfMTdXG7leSHx/a3@zmML7QUx8CxMeDUqd0Y/b884AwwwisUBJAlkhIxs1iij7E105hvIeIGZboIWWv7AXH3h07wOJIGF7FWja9aJs/EwGJvYgxx@c1R6t32ytweiE7F9vr76Yq1g6bBbv7j8@wnroeiwFHVsAPM4rNMoyRglO7DwoZFihuXW7E8MnM1iRgzBrjqNPmKcB223EbdkQkGGzQ3xKp0emuilfKRDSlAAjnlL8evMkSkZwI411cHWXDbGtMRvwFqJeEAas3Qn1Gtj/IOw9fBXQ1w3SDKQZDGKlwucC7sLknupPWUqSpsbCtyDWbyU4mMO46ZpQKousp9F71p6k7xt9GLIpow4XqnbqSQgMZ/EQii7ih6P7PcUZ0QqgCl6GHz5RfIbPH6SAe4o3F0jHJVGVSDjni6JeupIGS0bXZOQz/BWHAyqpmraFKjldyRSNPakOlkHBjFGA6GC156gjW8ccEHHEUlWSRawrxcd8Y05FYN3IJyC5Fj5Dpw7qzkSSkHFD5HvKiqFYFg6yAlT7UbXYaksn3QcC0XOGJl@ih4E/w@kyQz4m7DjBOgRtYwggI@iJEFlWsH2lYgS3KiDBuN0I6Km@elTBObO7JgL3TB5ejNm/xoggeydifrwicIetu0ZBEAmR8WGOX61SdpFA7ZOr1OOLI7nJL3m5cAWcq5QU8UU3MzamUvLLledreCLIxzWNRkV7kNR8Zo3buc06mHLlNjKiydhisE5Kv5HdokUIHrAE5desNVqkrNycpQpOSBDLRkTTktHTIJl6d29p3ZLwgiRGZP98uRLEQpAbyE@0@2ku0H6gs1z4xEXaSYWxxQFD2OA4zYZJx8Zsu6cDDG7PsJ50iJlCF4fMrrBCaLL0ClUXwRN2E/IUAQriawOoziDKG4dD0hL0@qNxp40k8ihGvuTHgef91mrpXJ4HOBDYmi6y3viXWMCKHcf12xmsexSte@i7SJWxmoJWR6vSmn2@0NYOjaw3YCjG0wcT3yUSge/F14NZfxCmM@CodRIqEU/VIPLJt690zTDcd8JtTAYobdCyyP@oCZd@mghyuFJxpk1YQPzKh7dUkrHYLycF/ZmlLIJNKGwpETETbEmbm85FxNUhgz1iYJBqDcXZLNJ9eC5gx5@N/3hrzj34xKo1/JbOjKpAZJ0gdxJlR7FeGyOuOmDfkgaDegK1IBoSuRZkaYNVWGOfiHZSdo1paLomBi7lFry4/VoJlXWUlBRxLiydmC@tQx0JlJpRYYG1cFC8yurhMqsDdfdvZsxihYaP7YWqdOeFikbvIgoPlFLR3xiuamfPuGTVPIXn4Q4euALnnHLJSgijGtWPFedlnOEH9oUfAz8YcvUicJKptUYoPqNtj79HvGiUh3KsH/Nxij0J7ADaGaDcZZg1O0/9S969Z1@t9EJ@kED9mkYun3MEg8fJ/SIHdYZ9m9CugWIElpGptYkeub4MhyGDd/1uWTBCM0VjvyBbZopjIaT0gWHiSDNORoBRvdbEn8PkjHSdJnnq1EhK@5/SvZ4eadwb9ln@VmF@UQfAUgBt5WwoGAf0hE5JhnOp4WpDOcPZTBwPBcZ0XDusdiLYfwSSETHMDGMFTJTZglmI3Bndi/GtdbYbVEMwiEGWvJ3fby@JrTps9vAK4NBirxCS4ENkV/PGUX5FGWMcQjxYXI/uVde/MHYAwI/gX7@2SxumcUIJOLaKtpSyPsVGWUUcCHzwIBkNElikGJBB2ahbgxofZyEGk@e3EcNsvyBRZEMszfFlTgibdj44GV1dh1ETn3i4KSyKBYdituBS5DSyM7dz7D@9@xnafDjIS5rzlAw7UjItoH0faRqApXwUtaEea2JMsdU/v6IWVl5bK8lCFicZXJmXA5sp9TKhTxQAp5f8VirPwRhnEpQT5p6LIaj/mDxkdS7V3bMjMw2i9ZNx/muITAzWxEmy6UWkbY4wcdJwUrik2CaOMXI0gx4CLev9KzZPEnEcbGO461Yn3yHDvfRLLKb0pOK7u8Wj32cFK/RoldNNHpIEe4YpLSgv9fq0PD6/RJEwuTtVZ0kRh1FRn3CjwaoBJk0lR5PIeI@iXuCHi2gHNbbAtqZ/XMvUZNGcirkqUqKBblEemLgdnTaBLk0aKPxBYaJ4xWuFlJ6wTl2J3SUl8@cY5BhTGCAuCr2M5EeijW4UWcl@IhuB2jbdbQWyqMkgqct08JBB/3XBKOo/FK5Iy0e6pNM/qzAkMYaEuwqKNdDkJS/ObzW6mOCMkUKGOIzSKFbNCWbLh7fqp9tC@QDCFyakqWlb87FxjhiGbCBP2ZSfYxr4KgqWTI2ouIDoU6iAcYC7FI6XZ@3q7j6C4bM8WjdIIcRbCD4s40/y7IEhvNey2lqY5Fxa4JZHEluHm2OyGxxkYih@B3JL4ciL3Vp4woAfMYYyhfzAAHDmhL2eChAoXdMzoshKvsIChbzOCzhI0VFjew8Z6QjUWWG56tGjtysHC9NGJmZQGBhMTtPhAisWWZniaDARDcTFyPHi9ntiXLAgljxPlMcukL2SpyGuueYgHSNcs6JJEotL9yc5GBKfL7qxBI1f1Pqy5yRmkumAn00hrVMPpm6noulxqpdWYkXjZUEejhmrbFEIIVjIqylws/9I9cUM@S5tgk1NhmxVYa0z8ZrrmGXCfs27y@h2CSnbLXGUPBMz3C1/arzFSuxoOwPB2AXi3RkgLHbf7q1yjJVYSLvCqC4dMrZxeYNIa1YUzjVY7Nwp6si7ekABWpP22@LD8d7e7Gwr@cTZWh06Q9Xc7kcMvG5Gfxe2VajKinoZ@O5s@2rbjc7uPnT8MN5lmS/79OVABtqB@1Dl8CgCL3@sMM3QyAOkBVzZ6QjK@71r9pt8woGPKHEzoNu45wyGoKgCSjQRi8fjkkBRCDlBPsFG4jt@yL06Ltp8EJTQlHHUFAaTYKvU@r0DMiDH9pon61PqggYCmZlzQTzllPc@oYzCN5sQp1F4Yudb5F5cuqt3@32XfER7xHGSAFzd8kCe3tmgRxnwRNG8u69CikerSv866Br@BVjFpPXEZyamNQ9EyouPMbGP/I75fHATtU@p2BagSYvYzOXMT61K1KdlCODxT8CLPMhoP2o3JeNgd0kOiUzw1QvR3D0BBg9y7sz9z6xLA7pxCTNvp8biTobXY@CNUDTHVoLqFj21L3Uknuya@KmTsf5NtIwxzAkThhz5XEl0NXsjxOL16N2@3FSka4B4I79IYnIN6H8nECkMwAagXL4AT0xiva/ZWBY7yUCivACBy/rmJY7WKCOBSzrSbP4241dKpXEwmB5WZRK2/CQyYjSdkns4oftbbEL79v4/rS4srpaYJm763yDj9vq453YBhik4VxuXgx34RXSiug3htba2MUL2eKCW1ioFze3CmG2VtpGt354@vu//@ff/@O/siX58j/4sk0vtc86k@d52YXmt4WndwV8r@2eLS6c1xYGZ4udAnLZPyhqeL8yyjQi81FveG6leRYwvpIdqdpnU/QZWVSo@/0uG8NfQbpsiHQzzKbl15BvjiIZm276xncf/SjPYQuvLh1IbuUBiTQAnaA6Hnqn6aMBHsw3QEnABe1AuTyfrSjFPYaD0Rn0qUpaRuKhNeu1jz4tUSQF9MWFGSsT9EK/hxrwa1rzcvMsqwG/wagu@Tf7@V3Y2e6PxdKpLZZyYskVS6kU/eTXXsJXZyEboHcuZ4PtQCrlQkp0tIBmhiIMaKFH@we6aydBbstaoCt7EJIKU0GZ2QvO1bs/cpbhC9fCjjWH12cKVpHQIRMWSX9b6N1Bt3yDHHepmKsNLRTqchdDlRknKrp/cQnUCNkQIKr5kgmy0Ycq8aSPPJLxKau@yL626DYhAoxkPXqzR@MeP8BctNCTNs@xvRRec0Tm8/wV58YCO0MT2pjC9UcI0IEKbydz5Em4mF602MrbaCU1k72wzfZJ5mNbh4k/UrbpXOh3YTABW3ObhFvoSb8WacjNxysiFejjFaOqVNL2W1hGkcur7igYSHcFqh0H1Ddd2x2PJOxRAsRwOGb/xvQII0WBihSV6Ba@LGsiWn1sOo@EnnRNhw52PD45MoiQ/WzD2L5NjG0nS14iih2YBwgpbcrXbgTdUEZdGRKxO43hOd4O2GjThWojPjcjfR5emJrAuN/WSHsEmUzOo/EMTUkPho3OZcMV6YP@8bAxqcC0BSufUdNzoIUYggmRwMEnq57VPIUwt0h2CVFEN4Ush/Dygu5EXo/GfZvSPifYpWooyLArOAhi7ESU9G9jfZWgY8TVP9AJJspTwlufRkoRS5IXLY0kpJTpNkPDbGroWKoGc@zogZOyGFU9MhUvyEJXONFe0sEvSPIuxgiQdaekF6B0RVh7ifXj7NTxe43Y5DToWsrRP1sQPC/ieKarKNkayVKXoOajG@8QK1hHfo5HgeC5SYUzsuZse@40lNe5pc15hIJ8a1v8bEME@gI6usCMPEPESS9gYZmYoaI7MDxRIct/gNDuNjqA3@SmMUFWPE3br@azTu3zae9syT7t3Z5@dQgTKZLVLJsRaXmYrSSWHCswM2bd2KuySgtVqMHTXjzDaU@wD4tBAkAka9c@Z89us4DQaRrvkT9NM0FiXYaYZB@uL4vgs1NopuNYZNPWnLPkqM63X@UdAXMr/WIf8geHfwELtakkNT3sc4ZtAEV@ur9dsctJmF1fyT1fyT@HnVDHH2eG/hXOt5nw6twfw1IixO0sTD2nX2PcECPE3ThsFODjGNrJ15qw70konZSkCJXDnOqxNFtBGY95AvIDlSlcKrq4ODpPAw8fccPvCmA5lZdiQbHpoMF9Ns6fYf8S62mEKNeS3iHMkWhlwDYipELNIGR1@cp9HOqo4bJIfk6e2MHYrQQEujebNmaLXr@XkYs1x1ss4CIavWa667n1XHKMTg3R2AhdkIupxXmR33r14m//ffhbepTeWsl@HMLvKP1bem09zY/wAG/P1Nt1eiu9idnW7tKTLOyB4fHF3/4Xym/9CeBgymQT/mytKlhrk/RWpkhFbtNba/CQX1mBev/vr3@FNizwjg3vYl2ou4IQKyiK7DR6xLuQLirYSt6WLkZihRyzEAZbGMLeHF7QMGq8sp4jNV1aWlVc@zLylbJHkVM8GWaNyFSINRnKngJWRlygiBVkGKQyoWgLw3ZDmW0g80Zoii9PvLUQdgBfpDmHrlKbbjwJ0WRogbdF0IE21wj7eX7Yyr1KafOOjZSyKSmoJSRu7aSsXX9W@H8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2cpox)

I use [Python interpreter](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/files/poetic-py.zip).

Poetic code is on line 38, it corresponds to brainfuck program `-[>+<-----]>.-.+++++.`:

```
-      [ >       +     <        -----      ]  >       .       -      .       +++++     .       exit
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
```

`aatq` on line 1 was changed to `a a tqx` to open two loops to skip over subsequent instructions (`x` is for Beatnik).
Brian & Chuck `?63` was moved further on the line: `{?63#k9 #`.
`{` cancels effect of `}` in B&C, `#k9` skips several instructions in Befunge-98, `9` is also for YABALL.
Second `#` reopens string in Turtlèd.

On line 16 nesting level of Poetic loops is about 50. To close all these loops a lot of two-letter words needed.
To save bytes I placed Poetic code after line 25 because Moorhens `ho ho .. MU` closes all these loops for free.
To further adjust nesting level I used `x x x x x` on line 3 and `M M M` on line 14.

How to keep it working: add/remove spaces between `M`s on line 14. Too many spaces: `ERROR: Mismatched IF/EIF`.
Too few spaces: program hangs.

Answer (score 4):

## 330. [Windows Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), 14825 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@     <!--    (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####&:#######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//      n&goto e 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnM n M M M M'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'W(WWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
:e
echo 330
exit




































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr33461*  prstd!\0k:4op>asequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05r"93"$/""Ha在ｕR 
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4UE8CLDZbPI2dbubFMm@fSUQjS4ABaCaQBW6CiCBZrND0uxqLds769HIDln2@Mqa9ay8nojxTuys5R17JsLejxOO@eQf0H5sbDg2rH@gPedkVqFAAmC3PY7Y2NgiUZXPkydPnjx58t00vN7Pfx7Bhx05/Wm374zYyPRGrO1aF6arsgdTdt@wvJyekSQMteN2xwPTHnklKcI0xryR4Y5Y37C7Y6Nrsgi46mxm71j9kekmmWearGn2nUvwzzBmm5fswG5ZbYDERs65aVtvTBf8sow9NPtvB29HrOUMBobd9tjQtewR@eYYOzLA0hm3zpnR9Eau0RpZjg1eecae2X1j0GwbjIIPXZNH2mQAqnVOceZ9Cow9cVzPhBSclul5DjoWwdFwLefxztNPb4TX0uxTA5Aa9s3JjeQ1jT23TLd9M4bOPj/d37/pmmGfKY7N9m@jpGXZznjkHIxuws@xna5pG0xXi6p@0zMPxByZ/UK6kJ7zAr99y4XSNESplWYlY48HTdMF4osivLRGPRUinDqc4Myx@1NmTgAY4NiBYOaIWVhaLJdOY0j4PzFbjt2egQcnE@AAXHMwHE2ZwmxH8AB4OS7zhkbLVNpm3xpYI7PN@hZg53QENh6DAmfn5vTScaHgFc6KhIg3NFtWx8IoIgeehMz20GyOu8wZj4ZjQM9jbcszmn0I1pyyttkxxv1RkjXBD4hH7pc90xYoWXYX8/F85oIQbKgCHPt1DWhj9fsM0DlHdDBpj22hxyW6Y9CmSViabQS1NyMXQDL6np/7@YTnksF4R67TdY0BMGrbJBp8fnDEvJbjgg1@GJbXglVgWsaIbW2x6N7Th1FWDciouk0pIGmFXTHGIr4nuzD6Y9NjA2MKadsjqFzMofLzY0gQnEXXoiUWzWSYnmbZLMtCZSswPZdmUCWKYIBaq2c0@OWZXmBZDfg@F01iOh3X6Fp9k0PpOv0OAtpEjtVzTId3OssyWiGa5CFalM4myxRYfpNt5tgmvIusqENCCDXLtGIOfnn4AZQiYKHBL5PlqQWsgSwF2WC7rGMMrP6UQx8OEXyL5TS2CRABVQ0g6wWAUNQRwvwThjfqAXF7xgWAVPrWOYoMM5AaWGIp@KQ2NlIktlA@8iS9ntnvY6pALCBTrsA2IdU8ZDwLKQMt9YLuZ77bo@wTXptp@AGOm5DjApA4DdRKI7k24Qd2EEU6yBwdBIwOMkPXwF0HcwahQrg8@OWhvPJZH7reJtqChIW4GhIThYqGNIBoUAgsA0WRZ1ko4gwWcS7DAE9AYDPPQK4UNFbIssImA3IV0wxIrwEyWP4ayDMNkNAQGBSrBuWqASIaMIwGQLVMjkkhumoZ9Ie4GYgLJNCyECcLZigXLY8/iAcFr0GSGqSp68UZewFueg4ymcsQ3@l5KLxN8ANi6YCrDtyiA7Z6AfwxbgEIV0C23PQJYfSHPQNpASWAzAysBgTJAU4EG8KDWd/McJai0E1zZLV47CZxcB6ZPI@khKhpzCJ8s0hRQCcNYJDBIQs6lHYG64J0LUG15E1oWGT54gdFCIgjZjBsgYF7Z6wXC0RoHCTavLQbe2YfWBCEUMsAM/I8iAsUPT4ca6SioIZ2znQusCUm@TGXjEcypuliMwwCr226LsOw0Fp7SZJG3rjpma/H2FjP8OqAeDNBMncMqx8gQPXOGFFDAt@oB@lN59HuuM6AKucApU3fcYZL5DbItksE9Mi5NGeoz0SfMRz2oUEAdxMIMTb6gMylQQoF6RvhVDlCEAnjtXoWAKSkQDBbrtki2ousQ@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@wpkKJmoIgVPRRQCGwz0IEZFyj96a3kIcTFjdTllxhmDoOX8hIchlQTUD0k2TAeoQRBoWi1eigCRyhkSEWBSuaOb2cf3MLJuwOmdIK0ERsNpI2kpgInxGM5DAV@/duA1GEfYVXnHDDonMMdoA1vsACyEyDZb4dd1ZShgiy8C@jAsZ0FUIGYAVwMMu9DZUHMeIJSw@gHzEjVxZsrI5TTs84ztl/QdA6Hjgs1gwudKUoyXmQh7nJ4RycWNBFx6HjPt6jQUkSxnR@NeKdt2IeOFFUxrKmgjBogKUCI8S4EyDyHpxhCmGo9wRL4XZLE58wETahtm6jPGu6UA4HsQasMCU2Z5bogBi@wbeBNj9@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@1SzddEhZ2UIem9rxROna41RW1UvrYRgzwA8bq2FjxPkwsiS8meJMQqrStAWNy8Qn5@HxZzdJApoQkoNSADP@bqg0PAwoXVLT8Ho3GmHWTSQgySCKH5YpB8yHGRgQdfQ3fHyOxm/eYOHdRGoo3BGz/tjgAHzH1IHtx1PR84YC5ns1O7xFpLighVo2DqDOTOGQPj6fotZ8ExlSpUMs8@nh/t5xhcD2DO/c7PcVCpLyRqBLGW5bBZ7vj9umtCgMiD8wtVhCnSGO@jThupDArdYcgWdly5bABwDYxVEdpvQHfta8HuC@ezNv5Kq0Ag4gO0G4qVeG9aHWxyIawgObuBb2dBe1ouQxa6wCp4UtVuA732y1cjlzM1sMN1utWZrtMNABKcWW4@uNLnidewq6qDMtUqjVAv2Tx7cQ90iJhK6A4mPm9ZlKaXl9CXsvisWiXmoXemhO31Sfk8STmRxPpaL@yKna8qjPGQq/N7FGsXScf7U4hIXUd3YO9Id@YDHKRwMY1GnALji2TG4HZypaHvCI7fSdrsM2IA7XDv0EQW1ams2drmPfKiEDHTGrEZz6APmL4zXGENoa6w11HClWuLvKp00M27sEKa3lM0gkohCBSlF49ZVxYQC5Zvk@OfjGHjQiWi6dDsxpeoAEoThELjS1Qq7kwBRISBX4LMxgMA1yq7b7HkpoHgIzLQRdEHFn5r3QkSSmmloYfiFKX3VuUfyVM73BWuDCWQsMIZIdPD16fPB078nOF2cjPZebs2fTxTwQDtJrgi6k9jjdsLZu8KqJ2UJwEagbLlYvkAJj6KD44@ljzwXBrWIQlSOwhGv4BFLsq07Pjnrxm5m5RF/lld3iLPQEKx8PKiJCR7vdx86Iy@fdsD1H/umNRkOvlEpBLe@Nmyp0WlOvWk7f6KYoHjQM/X5Kw67LwSGOa3iLYgAy3tTkMfiYFqgOUxo4NPoDBzovNJeHooHFOHgarOpb3R70hXHCz3TjasDBlJtUG3oI0FdOBXkjAUw2oK34@uUkc9b@iqYXOF9raT2bkv1gc9Ufwq51TOg6xaC1AlLEb1jZ2b2ze2wKUhoh3QQSYeqGmPPBtqDPQJGkwVLs5/vEIWmBw6QoK4hGr8c4iAtSKpVLZze1fC4F3TLopoHOquBQmzIwRq2eMnIUgKc4HRo3CHFhx2sZdkfdEAYfWdD7PoGsZmovzs7sOijoZ/cIN5xJq03rNa0eL7PbUTZE@HgZuHcue8i7vgPwLhmBNenLlsiztnFbnLUNql1tlhoNhqLNUYbsyQ4oUm8ckNdtM1z3MEIq7JnamAubwsDvUgsGhPoYVcIXUioFFQpaWmC9FOKlgNKL6iFwDsitUAQ2G83g@eDz1yE5gp1u5HvLiXo00I96DQ6SekMgIo0xt1BKezg@OILWMeB8lNJQuCik2aUZxeFzw@ODlBBJzFr68aGvFkCgwfhgINoOZmuBCSgWdc9BcgBf4WhpbzbKiJ1@4DRIkHDCwQfQIGyaNOiCnIHIPCM7PCM8JXKZz9K57VzaCK1psoLStEZ8jN8ZuzgbaLXDeYPgGZ2HAWiUuZBcp2nDptnio6w8MuUCOoEGG5gDB4cSQLsiUWBSFgw@5Yh9QQ8HqqFapRWcdQH4Cru/C1KsZfLxImWAnShgqT0WHbmpHeUbKUN5A9y8QrfCzO@EZ8Cp0E99AtBIZDAFTqMkYgSUtBNnQIGe03gLej7w1V1pOB31IMfAYbJRcYamfbPPx3uEsXiZJmqjURD4lh27iq6trUVL0Wo0CaZtMG2haRtNCTBtk0khE4ZT0UQxkmRC3xrFQLd69LrmQ57E68gDE9Qc3ljDmFErlTL1pFHTxFfHbxyKAigPoRX8AJxovFJBYzwuVy9xqgb091Ded5F3TlquNRQk@CooBNwuaJAhIkD3HrV51yxj33Q1RQYVFzqNJqqYMTd6Vkuf1c@uztqJs@toEmPHy0YF@ocgvEaxgdp1nfEQFLdatqSAbIvXMqV6uVmJpqMbsVhB6UNCRjz@SSGeMDitY1ETeCp2dhYFkgrq1Fo9l@BNkno8HhAK8OhY0Mvo92NR9aoA6Tfj9XgiCnHj0SSI5Uo0CnRpIRE8yjSOCHAm2rcmQEqomNDEhecUSEDSnBRW12@Yw97UDQcIRt1Ay8YR9NlsPlQGkuJhKfmGxw8rdHM9fV/v5eFAucXBO9SXhlMu3SWO6VlqbmWJ3@5eKJ2BMzJSn6vQaVJDzWV0LZpSFGgJyYdDomw/sTyswoZtOmMvPNK4cAAUUwfX094YhKW/7CYJXGUNJbPVc1h0/T5AZ8E0DzYlOGOl8HkvH0C7pcIPhShqJThZAtoFrUexQC7iWhU@KqMRElz0@GPzufzwtRqkVqY4LI0JWV3bcU0FSAIxJFo9QmuNpCoTS1IOaOTr1ryE8KUmDTvelgkScb/vGERbLq5D80HDQSg@9M8hyrHZlvogPzogHlVeFq7ZTm1INDnruD1oISA3KIn1oLQGwiPleMO2OppAVCmGDW7Yk/fuQOm8ZG1d1/OtXKfk@yFXALF7UEjYK7Whi@t7KRp4xkUh7/FhIb@P/vTw4R4fO6HGFptXHEdrDJz2GPRK0W86Nu1uku0BP1m2M7CADH78N@f9Y8cZ8V4@WJaNzPBOszUY9w0a87k5LLMyXstpOn0aCloVdRZ@7HpG3@CDUL7vzudPQNd/dnpSUUuhQCnjYrAybRyHXJwsp@dBeM6Rpln96SGPM6a8npOx3fJXs6GYER559BiLtWxQRr77Jrr7VQrnUIR7Ad0HuI4NdGUxikDWwFEELFJAXNuGS4KE45WWvkb3pX2wIJxG4bjiOMP2StPJ/WLU6cw5Z8j5XEHR1J85Z8mZr3Gb6yOGUcrxQLjgbS5MGFCewgTr3m6GE8IrWGLQM/v@DOIxKCY4SwZtex/VJ@iboCbOF5@ZoEgPcTKEJDROsbEW6JrerWELqFNDhYeWImtUT6ANS6HmIq2nmBjiLlNNsR0xNelx6elA155GT7aqfMIau04u77Wl@OD7egNAbFXL/lKkZcEwpWg0CEZQCTeIQdmkaftbWQ0WYXg0pi5RlLLkpaDXMNHTytlkc6@e8ogIHSafnU0@SetfQOcDF42t30t1zTImt5RaZOfj0K0eiA2WmMyTDMphbHecflvhk15Q/ox3l7AgxFKDYNkaCXxwsVx/xZqFi1jEykIQl6HFbrfg3ii66u0AoeVxASCoDVfs7Xny4i2rQQt2oXrDvjWqs2t15DR6mPnR2LVvLqTjKqXrGlNPEitVKmzn@NPPa@k6hyANDJzIKvDSmvjrMEEPBr0Hl7uCCdfbjKwRNey0sMDC/GoqIDWhOQ9AH2DwBMosSEjkCFF/a76d5aVjQsczZiLm3nSQZGb8Wu30jdHItDlv8dnE5eTm0z4imQolvy3mEEosTRMtoGha6AcoltnJ6cO942MVONSLRfdwQqYE1c5o9UDfWJZpn5LhzJfYJ@0o@wTjxLEXLkGVgs5EQ8QH5i0Dc0N3AlJHUdA13Rg4xnEupQXONH1FEbnCJQiEq6ZaI6JRACxmxiFPBKy0EP9nNu85CTxLLMoSREkgd@xeCWhrxdWxbb1WPWg3SA2FIFHe96Q1tpX1GImvdS1O/ONaA5wLhi4TaYGQh1qNrYF0o9Ayq7xjL2pppVhPrLN6vcxn@CEi6vS0Zles/zQEPfl0GAlIgfOB6JV1bqwC9lOgkVuMxfHTgGclwbeArDtuTm/XUnldl@MBssobcOCe8k0kF6xS5Sj6S5tIhNBKqPkVTfPrpULZekad7BuryyE7PgJBfnAaMsZzydYqTIvHfcw4oOeGi13nEjtyPM9q9mn5a6dv8ZVgQWNdEoQRkHzKhJMrY8UgumF9hnqGhTFb88xXEgtKkD81NNCTwpyRQyzOrpCYREodqcjevkUHma3rjNhAxiXHnL7Xfp8W5ONjB5B9LJZQh3UOEhpieQqKjjNJ9jtv8/O/6MM7BqmLGzqvciGH43Gd07LPHZpFCkyNtKrlUM8MYg/O@7djdiyvR6@5oAEOPKy@DDtv0OzQa0EAmkwR0/TkQMP0QsOG4jRSx/ShEfsFKc8vTZlLtml2xnaX5jTRzJTXd4RUigUK3Gk2rWVBgQi42sz/LggGshJrnq5mVc2vPTjAA80iyE/eJ5pl/eaqJjZHd2ikRhBLfP/zN9tA/9ul04P2CsczA0MDNAUsKaWztLBEVLTQa3HB8mH3cd8yiDBkugtky3AhS0Y/MCwGTVP7igL6xgAnKkSJA2/iC3TRFWzGMefzjP53cSKLpupskNutZWFvrPLiSdGkEnQX20QErnNZJkUiIcsLwZzwiZ1Qxx0F7t1I@UuxGDEzL/feeDTmb1CH7yxEa4i/VXVThEznjKZmQofUaFrmiiJ3jfNx21GG591ALc4vCDvLPc0sK6CViEnmBhoXZ59n0LW60Nz732XBZu1r6pI@d3GFZ4@9odKkvn2b26giDFak4Pb5e1kQS2x1CgzLqWb16fWBnCigA6OINRYpXMGqhIhm3SBz32hOURXqfTyXBesVQOJUWolEOrNkwno4XB4f@6cUv1hcHHuitjg9Fo08pPgqWYWPzVGGxbrZO0oVmitrYPQVvR0yLhXmi5Y73AoazJRSHPMC54kuFpbcjPrYILXGfcOdmVaw@AwPf3Ji2Ti3aDaOrJYD6sCQaZuqpvtNR6jBIJHpL7ibJYSLlOkVWlRhLSJjG3qh2IgrgWmxCHBaI1yIuoSnPkCg8QWguMw2xCSqs4xSLecSf0vVhx70hPl7cYv2ZiFWHyCclH6rb0A7vrQ5mBtyxCHNOxj10vJMei0m7PlCREet/kL3@SrgDyaGBwfvYmvP6jseO6H3KgJ1XaACfy9m6DAtLcNWaIg9bF4hg/yVE7MCNfpdp58vdFMGvJaW@tjtoNwX3w@VcIGE0rQ7JJSv/ji2Jr5L5fp5yj2/q4Bo55iLq2ZDxhVN7CIxJWZ0lucOOgY4Hbg4Z/vpAsVUU3wAcUnCOJFzaUz979@j6VhGWr/pGE5JnQbtDiMUC2AYuVzF/vukll2dWvvDhNItsJt3ZSJUuOd9Exoret8qUqantY@MoaXTHy6iOv2xOTYXdjQOm69M3IS8opPx4UilRTbWxfg/Tjnghpcg1BvRM/wgrLGdRttKYWJAl928W5WZF2pD0L6H2HU@AsMRGm7H6Nrj4VypzvXO7OPVJOsN/SrttOewQ5@PlUOFOzSlOf3cM@m3ssfEe3i47KySTafTQoEJzePMWVb1pDJB3FcWf88lTC6zlGdhce7ODRkXp0FkCS9sXCqC9GUdewpcLKZsyzZHU3x/oDRtOk7/Y0oKhGrbQlUMNEtawLuqxG6pO2JrCpsNXXg44NHsLBu04K2N6FsCfbDTvKrQwxNNH1SaCk6lDnCaa966evgmNG11Vyq4GRzHhPiS3v5yXVKMhmhqQd1cWeu4huo0zb7BP5N8dhW8oppZCW9eaIgpYJwy5hPFswn@yA2hNJwCsaw29FJ65sAk6wot32i/Gnv@Z2mgiYO/Zd4T02ylJntma1mAoQVywcb33Mx0SFkaOTb0r0a4ehD7KX1cnypcl0lgfy5xIZEPBkbX5CdcrJKUswELXKPDu3Uz4@KhixJfl9OCaLPh5eUsAZXq3Jx6/nchwCfTFpTreHD3cNuNyt/CMdAPqO3LFsbebmLtntOze2aPr0YPbMsqB/DjiJ9Isgp1wLrbwwVyw@HcwvkwPftOv/8h9ETRyAWl43QW4rSHW2pxP9hHwZ0aTfAQnzsH74wRlx1oWFpreuYY2iXPGTlDUyHbsqB9HOjh72Uy1J/6/vuOIK3s5wNF/O/fF/6dfcuu4YyGQ/o0hv2xRy@KqtBO6Lv0pg5f8EJLLR23q75xBk1VOKpiNQzNuC8WMU1r1OrhDnTO2WbXabZ61l1IN01jZFvnKX/Ih1s/qO@KlLGY8hCd1b4F5HWnKvJLJex/gp@DZYUuRo94sxYYVugri0boaLO3MjTOWx4fDUUTK@GAcKg28i3hJdpLX3o9tkYzoKEVUsHwLp@WQMMy3MWajKWaFe28mIlhsVZjKZeSko4KuWKmQeHRliU7v3ouVMUyGf5ahlA4l4RRaLXLx5BbrCii0UErNG4L7nP8NbcUamEjZ/fGXe@2wOTD9W1Q0fC1fNiCVkiHhqyhzTJs8VlGZr2fwq2T8G2AzjU2V86p5FZOqlA4ra8YjgWfBnyg6MZLx9D61tDjb6Z0lk7FiRVS0Be/OV/IaTNd3JkWBdM2O3wKBE13qYgDhyZpQQdRWjihjyPoKMy54sUFl@10QagrfTYL7IddprYsXHy0uPiDNlP54qnZNXAF92NrhEtAF3AFseyiRUt3wv7a2PCsr40hZ8uYDc@B4NOQbvjAALQtgPfE6FqtR3MFESApCCzWj/LPHPuj0@2yuOxZHi6gCgwrBqaQ5TgTI9c1oN@wIOTNcfvgCIxZBeKbKxeGXjS27gynuAdtSqZVw@rWiEZZxXdZ13HZ0rKVSFyOB8OxJz6LcaAlWuFR6ME5uXuXFgBXXoNoZT2jP1o8Uh0acgUtTDSKM@MybfwbVt/psm8U0gyUNlDCUDlfwDgPoHk@wnVBrr2AEyntD5z2xIEOxeUZew1la2aYYtnWaPVozmiEa4T8L2aGtxy47yH1GN/q/Y@FoJwupsjju3X92YbnO9p34LwTZ@y2TDQGp5iEuwUiVXPXX9OM@0QcPIXlMtxLazl9qF5g6C@sMi3HHo8Ud2yvbBXyK1uFEpsU8iE2YLGv7T15Fg9zA60Bv0sLNaHzN/b605lp6YKBG0xm2aCILZej86H9vsRDfujSMS1AviPODp4M1SJx/dBZ1N85mrrm6IM7TCD8x4OHZgunDe9M@6nzxLEdaI2GICgHxyY/SWBuocfiiBjtMe6VB/q070zmhMAuaYS4tmEMzSaUb39m@pC2iAN@aIyMJU0RjQ1S/y8w3ckrVr9puq9o0C9kXtalnUfokTmhvsVyhuF1UBm1WlwlxvG4uToyN2PjDR3H5m@Stmn4aE9WSxVoCuj14RPlKi7vnxsXWNg/m8/q4QVfJWK2@VEXy/Lqmk2nz98r1iTZFl8TYLiW6aUe48kJ5JbPMgW0L2@lDNlcKUNmXSPQZC8MjybpF3c1ZiC1yUcsAeoZbsvBmTBhWLE6J3TcwR1iOtgxwBcONIHwE5BYRmssTm28C63@oDmg19IOQ6g0j80m7jVq0hkhI2NyuzD5yJA4ICG0ois4VsAXV1ip8yx2BL2R@N3N1lw/ap6q1pBeJKmXTpfTYh3FtszWGwNHzRyi12xses4f8px6SsYlY9WhakSjyCmD9s8vrEnzS9dAoembyqjnQp8/NVo1vO0f3rJgPmQ8MHGSeX4WZqnq6ng9yqyzeD49EK6uqYiDA0GWBIcIcv1Q2VmqeSJ4@D988NUUNMKNfNY/0ARE190z@ID82LXF50M48MjxRh1rcgh446aDZeIEs5WDKPDhNQNNG8syAaVnj/t89KEbWnc1aFN3TKHTbxWlT@J6ZCqmfaHQ8XKT2zly@Fay1A4eozoy24o4XQFnGpTH/q6yIJj4LphADctGXOyppThhJ/msWP65iLiXvmQAfcsZKUOPvqmhd3Tw@PBUHXrawvZpp4ebMW7pcXPHNeiFdGhI6pXhhuY7@XK0tuWNUg9ONGX38YGKAZbQm89oKPDBmbm5z9JxT3FoqZEylvaC0NccLVYQH50@eZyYbfxksd2e6wzMeNh79@QkiRtbvnqy0Dscex9qR8eZLI1@sKdp8QXs@8ym2cFl0nNBSssgnZrQGwVmfMRPe7lTuWo5Q7N9Oh2an0PjiRLc@8Dk80sz@dS4sLpYC1lxKaGoorKims/GQyuzobNtusF3WXmeW0OUli36pPhn6XIU1BwyKTezWHtYNeN/U4thabES4eMiaenb3DqyFKgZ3R6aUob3D0VM07RldD4xOlCuLLe0sOYDLJof7jsXHzCVbIrOixI4KSPgKsW6cx35pjIA0Z3CFw7PC0cwNpcug1kFIHDOL6zwl6Y9NWyF5rJWqRcliI2L2lYG@Yb5ARNSwQqfCzxKeuEcX7CknsVaZIzfkfCpG4qyu/vg4K4Ix4KWq0N9@vQZOzI8PNpkdcAwxuYHYDzTjF4pOG6F5@otnU5tuwBKXwmvO1xcn0vsxHDbjj2d3D0JRztbsWmnk4oDWGijQGbfmliL2qoWH9c6WrzM6K60@SYOZzqnB4ePvBGA3n/nn2taOk0HGuFXS3PrHSXjV3AWQ5MxxVPywl6nB4FoaKHeooJDfGFv9LE5weUofDR4Uad@YfuWX9H2bcaXNyer/Aor/LIr0rvlh44so6a1FQBzK/xYTg28Hzv9y56j7hqu6S1Yf7wQoVUZKa7ISDEknd8U0jgIShOLwrxcxcetC@KzkFtPzZGbHfacppVdmIedDh5dyZ7gyeu3/cVyCsOl5S1dR2z54PbF6V2OzYUJPTHeLPYgSXO@0AuEoNkb05aI297zE6RN0HlNu2vxUxvZA2e0R7aFSB45uGJ9YZIPreHD8XA5oiAS8Z6Am1J8PiDuhEMz3912PLbD5y17SXFiBt@UyrcJeqp/KHYsZicS8fj8pQ3hTZF8OyCeysd38kHYt2/ZmtiwBx7BHkaxTRAP74IOhImbayUCgbs3Y3alouWKbBuvTiiBehCnFNGJjkjy06qx9Sux@65U0q5xB6JckpnYHRmceMpP7QS4eN4g5Ikp5xpbH4HPur93j9G58@wtoy4H6DhaLg02NRXeTF0WmxoBpfWro4OjvZPTndNnJ7V0/VqOi627HDfbhtT8Td2fZNoy5F2QDUQZP8OXNv/2ITk6Ex@7Kp6fLwY5u5G1ylzWZpmStzHO@pVtp1K0hzWlXAN@isxTI1/QS9CJw/ZzTOUjtiCX@NbPPpFUXuegZUoTyqzE0osSHhpQLddt4X/zSg/yZZkM@vKExbGrwJRdx2mLFD2T3f34Ke7vHDx@drzHfARnTHNptUe9SjHHT@XF5l4xoZw6Fq2IqbCoiBKFsqpUovtRIExUjbIS7RymE3GBzyGYTx3ccyxib7DYOsEHCkaDQkn952@mrqMqLu6MQ9ioj1SUCcpjAHaKuwH/7CdtfmK8fwaIf3eNO6C2jc5akMRO3yX7fJGiVDGHy2@woRPaaUtvcDT87FYgiS4MAK68pOO7bhztFKfTVvh1ROLkLT8hYhD/lGkcJcRTtFyPXVi4n5fj0MFDreZZGRcW0EFuKtvB63mA55lBtxYA6mN7xA@OEcdMRICP1ECgJNk6IcvvOJBDAaNba8DKTROEJ/Ns6HqZoxJ7BXyGI3ElvqlcUarRW1F80PxeJqU3GvRDAW@dguWlzkap97/63VS3zMA8ST8A2y8LWwfMv8LNL1JY1rdPypqlH0YCT7cTWPPEA5ojvUM3Edl88/6MWHigly8pmTWAorkgSmNwngJ/KyBgZ3Bitc@hoIDFoJTEpn2enunWY3i8XimVQjbCRlyltcrmhC8cunHMXj6Xz2opQFK58AHSudhd3BHJAcbjJWB86cIaVl42gb22tpiMmrxZyZd5aabW7RcZ@WWA6DqElS57iFyNQRyIMosBflURDZqThBbHqCiPoloURVHbgXaG/LE9QrstCCGzGBCL08jEg5YneCXVyJ36x0U28Zqn0J0J6wKQokErQ6a4LIl95k@dEbDM3A57vs8cF87xNg3PYfP4lWt0SiPyoHq7Ns22R/qXM4j6pWK956Ay6ZvNY7hs5ecI4gRBlORFLFt7wc5GZ3Y9xXmTAZv@SLBsmJltMP9SqruEZ3m@d26f0Re7ecIeEovdP7Ed7LLsQ2ZYTE/pmZSWj8@ylM0uzJLIkUgGsoMnh7yF5EA0gZhomdYrZ@jt7O4dfPXw6OTWOXQUMnozGEjy6lbiTFGTtXpgiIazNV8kD/ZTJ08e7PsFMUM6H5LAoL2InGircjIbiUCQs5XtN7O2CMObuVuO8XO@9/Umvhl9FWoU6RYeWvoj0qXVpco@7RG5mbheWEStXG4VSjN4qRDoXb7B7xaqsfjVda2@VT2zI9HbnLCgIryIqBtYCcB05m2sp5DZb2cOMxZcjXiKdzJ54bqYWVwX5fUMHoeE@4tHzvnsICjhEPII5ddPBkSkpKb8oEtr3yHXumfHlen86kZ@cFL4uJgQwvn0KoqHQJ36t0CiFJkdtijOGewZXq9vNSX/mB5@3qB/LFpw1CA/YicWl8SR/TzhmLgXclKaqLSUJBZHaUewkmzV0YU@vLgEFRr1taMx9OGOnCE/wpmmDB@avunYAfELPSFae2Cyr44HEK5Dn2OThm9BcisQGSgZDVDl@hNICXFy4SSBZ0NCejU8v1BkXB20c7FJXO2Zk7bVBdkeiydBon2iaXUWnG6ImabTDO2oTGU2K4WVVfFT3LYZJvtHHXE5mSFg1AzVstvmJBa9jMZLdUgf3aOXzy@icXkRL9FRm@LsyfbNMzcD9De11ZLEGIna6R9ouUhaFIu3pQS43QTMD4vy748pFtWeJ9E1YBXUxU9G7mMwghoR6wyMIYuNbX6glsrIGjuL2Uk6gUip8jP5bJZIUBcJPuShMorZIRNvv2OGPWWxVAWYAF09u42fN9aQ1TRVrYOZEomzdbzXaRc0LjycJi5BrxailAhsBVkIOg6AEa8kKmdwiIP@Ep4Z5NKxZAu86ZobGuVykCaUa1a9x0LXc81rjnKxWBIFOi8Viwy477Y4VFMA9pac83V5oK44/AJoBh1aVYrMBPltiRehdCMckUfi1AxAJxI6R9M/TIMBrNkpl62ei7/Yng11Bc//KT073W8U4imZBadvdF2rjaOw/CjooNMmLu@AapqaCxot8z7apxgNj1Vr8OM98NSvfaow8g2RGgmT4eZttzPe1LSVXC8iilKAkFlsAMQupYYPDs8P9OfDF/gtFvY//znepyvH1jXtvOFeJKK5dBleWjnHcuyT9TNFWa@lK/fXDeg5jV5PzmRmpLIbDy/MXqd50E2dyTLLsGwqtRHd3ziy9PyL15PrjFZ4fT7U8jX19aQuFyrJ8/qEHR198a7xLi5PLqbyWYx6k2z38K2sZbGzGikV2dV2PhM5L6KH/7zhH33Zc7OXLkdlFjk7w3ty5U05lapF6/BPXi/h4YFqVbWqbtffvYvXmGGMJlN2FsG7J9nhffKnjhKONOl6/MSyrBQ7G3rtNvycHqvzC5Qj/EkkYgoTDkqNu5UHkw65TXbMbne8Z0y5uxUZ42d/JOI@@cbz58/R8Jwe9uY4ImBT7HslEa7UMHIRpqf1P/vp2nXy6qix9WffGqTMNfwc4ue710/QfKLlPllb@@TBg2w2CaTh5qNvHH19Z2cn@zCZO6rltrNKem3rT/9kbU3Xt/TUWt3ztHq0dn7@hayns7L6Zz@ONo6OvuZ51cz/8c13VQ1fm/C6YJsgJ@DJMA2M@C7AT0Md65y9gee8w/CfzG/aIbOB5mbnDYu8iQCXa5Ep/TVmhbzGtOr25n/5/uHryChS1VPPXfiOIq8j@UKEG8EAtoxvu4hUI1sYLH8dmaYqlQoYN//Lv4X41a8CHPSZbsGrmvNh5aeRqlKhKG8j1TwYNF2HdP@vb34zxDxcTFRIjfOf@6wGj5zd1OXtOjwb9GxJeOaZkk6leCj7XteB1sxkWuGedg/so97IdPBj8Y9t4uHTShl63ce1RCJRVxsKPOoL6rtrmn4GAoDNsRbVEKKSsHIXFnYTHjwwZ53nEeIpYCriK24WDsRq3OH5zXDPFzzl5//Yz7EUya/dNx9WqyAKM9XMRjVBz9pZqcTJn2KbBdlx7oOQSLLomRxlL9ljUThVOV3Q5WQyeb@B1gmSVJlEZgRknEYsMkfZCJvZWNgpwvxobBbmY8Pt4fPn/@uf/@DPv09/P6Dff8Dj4ey21UltQLwLqDpV/sBXrrry1RlZIMPpUqFUSDWuz2IbIKnqx0xLf/o2mstETwKmPIv7I5yR4KlW8UX/wkYm@t5wEz7VwEIhZlFWh/OJGoEmWCykU2oX1bqCilNFqWn5XF3h/OjnsVpktftQTLK@WZTrVT2nH0LRaTIvuN66x5wI9CDzEGkbnjX4o394AusajiKvkdua70Ohbj9rQbp3PgCzpG3omVTuk/yeLkVqtVTdrIMiy6o@kPtrpbVCKV/SU40VcFn5tpNpmkde5ELTWs1m802racDTNFqGNjLuq5tqQdW3xsbEmBqj5rg5aY5a45amSZF3tTV2zKtBnSX85yxx5/NMVRvCSAYHf4riTCJS5B/hqWq6xjZAkKbhBdoDGaFzh3@QDxa5gqf@bqP2bgM4pJrYoupZryoCS/iojfv1hHJ9XQNzuSz@t6qBsUwPN0Hm6teJxNaLqqLUXlRrCQD5QoBUOUy1Ua1vkUeQlkhMeEezTjTv3N@qM0g2sVXbqji79IOY8Ch1gLs1h@v9@wkVTPcBQHUdFIl4IrGuKGsow2tCVkHgejXhZwpxAO1mawsY4Hrrunpd27q@3tqC/y16X4svuF5v3fqnz@xZEmbmX2e1jF4AvKrVs1qqepY6E8xXB7uaqqKLmjoDQxW@EA4aMykC1dMsSZENthHB46MykQ0p8vL9l/8z/s7ef/n72NIz@JMiqQ3sIBR5PwFejD2x2RP@2Db8w8@3ogs6PKmio81f5MJSqZcqKyn8VHutkI@rKAwbTqeBe1FV9vIJSD4QEEzWC3m5kdCmOotsyflNFBG/cOuJRqP/5KVe3Izy7jRun3zpPQmhRYhBb@wJ/4Pwv7Do@Se/sOyRIm8hsyDhPMZzLkWA3BFFqUqR6tYA19Lh4LWC/YTPK18oz3YU7NgaI5qOaPFOW@Vgr1IsVvm4@/oR8cfGww14a/C/t@Z5eIkoJnOFr@Zr/Hv8Bv9ej/DvtIV/x6/xj52@wb/jEf6xJ038O/Lw7/Q1/u008e90gH8PXuPfkxH@PevinxSpsHVtXUv306201tSaYLBY2mXpXrqntUGVa2gsbbL0ND1l6YGjtcFkwl8aTFa6w9JdlrbTNgQEXzCNWHqEpg58uvDXAUAu/Fm4VqOppVsMEuqjwke3USF4ML1tnEk16LnKL03QxlVNTat5q45n@Nfkul4sMBXLUm3UXp5F63g4rF7MsubUXDt7ySIeaPLlSOrsLMXHJJieLeNx/9fXjcbe04eNRgrF3NkT53D2f3g4CFtX/g8OnSeHzsCB/8PDwyfMrCbuJ0AA3L9fAYEgPtuRann7rERixRctkdTW9lk1o6A5nwBpoaNb4iOfGUT4VtfOpOjz2PPnl2VSw8qXF@XLMhkCKxga5SCACMYN4FgW6hu4lH097hKei0tyxBcaL5@fBSZuSD2/PMPuCPQzg3/Qc8PW/wr/1v@7/p88Y3EWq9XjsavrrRg9cfyLx6@ur67FuxqPxYQltgV/6AB2jHJ1XUUjBboCUy0Wr8evr7kbvGPxLQ6wCslsVSnuLBxU/0iQJCXLX7H/ul9IWjxn0TIzZqsDzs4m6XS83PTPrMaZMeMtTdLGy3QD0XqzptX/9Md0Mvl2nALlsuWytsG4Rc/q5XLWt20WyuWCb1mPxYq3n2p6W8uDUpXNxuPlMli2fbBpsAZgCwDWt@QAqukZLar05cjVwSGd2Q0yIhfBQ/G5UIil6WR/vCQmKpfke/di4vLZ7Z34vXt6Mf32beAyHIKTNufUaLQtt9FA98zbt3JDpsn6Yg7s6cLbt1q6mNCicceNPcXbhSCpmKKxT/QqpVp0XKDEJngzLaXP8OgZnjEaubE31jAp45IzT47T5R/ptOOeRX/2vW996yxaqciKTK5ZDQFgKiy3tZXPVqv5LJjzBSCVvH7F78HpJopa/Ho9JXNyMHk9GhFeWmEzziVjFP2hJWXbVajeHj7s6jpC5c6yuXgMZGsctLTrCP5xZ61Y5O5xls3HComi@KusxVkVVAb@h73iTCK7sblxH5Qp/JssfFAkl6/MinZduTJLOLp4XW6Jyx1xl6p5716mCHQtpMtnUqPxcOd0p9GoyLKMLSK80JGEu4R3Sg3daI3KPFes1zCH9bNotFS@T/yhFXIMGEGEU6LQSrBCkQghWR3cgg65lzQx5rAm6fTFl1QUIxHgGMEmmf/a8LA2a7IuPqzLLMtiFuvTw/qM@9O71QoCOfwRvoGV4uITuJjBI0WOHu/s7p0m9S2FRfT9nd2kfvLsQURDa25mJ@8M2o/3dh4ePoMIR4/3dk72Pj34fO/ZEbh77HL2@IJevGffsGmB/ZI9l165bwzTNMyxaTYux@PL1@yVZTUsKL/@GDLhdF3mmQ3AfWjM8lGGX8vyjFevDHdID3v/o@@8/9F/8/53vvf@d77z/nd@8LMvf/Ad@P0Eft/j3@/9m2IO3z/78p//7vvf/h1w/A/w@yP4/fRnX/7GN/mP7H8Mv/8Ucvtj8QuF4z8JYP3yz778/o9/9uWv/BB@/1L8fnj796s/Xfz7wbeX/zDe9393dZjv/Vv4/R6H5Yf93m9zN/zeCv/bPNyv/PD9r/87/v@n4g@Nv/P@1/8YX8Lyz374p//p/bf@va4X/vRfv//2999/@1vvv/3d99/@p/r73/jXWjr8@t33P/iDv/rD3/urP/wf6P8n9P69D/l//8N/9hf/y1/8b3/xh@L3U/j9OzD99C/@PdSNv/2DH@H/9//gb//oR/j/P/2rv/2DX/vbX/4fyfCb3PB//8t/w99//av/8W9@67t/9dNv/s2v/fRvfvMP/up//5X/8zf@41//t7//1//9t9DxN3/6V3/0y3/5re/85bf/xV9@68sl7@@sfH/5Ae5f/iO4fDieHwLnQ/L1sS5f/r3w@YdQY5YK8Alw9y@9/41fBAb/dcbef@cnuKQbfkv@f6JrFOYn3Pb/AYN@O8/okwYT/H7t/Xe@hyT674BE8B/Q67uBZc6HW747swBZf2tBpF/62Zf/4sdki5ilKg1YY3Nd0AuJDejSbBSLoskWY9kQ5RfnoQUARErfRQk15/ddlG3vf/TN9z/@p@9/9Jvvf/TL2GAq2WJyJ6loq1dSQgur5D4gHAbMf0g4DPgFpp@gURsl8QXY2BfC84svvpAab1O4d@D@W3D9gpz4w7gX7i0QXr4fuuNmA/aWhc3CmBbGdeEapExYYKoJUjQ2fC0ol2GThEBogsOL@AV3CDTZIOME3@SK3hMJX7P/mXEisQSG4Q9eteQbySDiiSS4UcpBMonJxCcXqWWMq0Ib3IWmxijdbJFhDiaTxAT6u2CAFBLg9SDBKpVKAiNWOD5g5ahVC4xQSSQqkG@MzeMkGwUEMXlAUCBmJXHMGhuVCY@YQHhVnxwJCZ2OZU2XE4XKQ0iwMnnIEBYCJ7AvX1aqhcqkiuDecXokJokHhBMCqyQm1XdgrxBMiCdFHr4DVAqVRKJawAQxk7x4kg1eSDnKHOU9wRKiDOCLo83b9xn7RNYKcoNrh0gwHhrfiVnobZo33Ab/s8SGyA79@0b6bRDB1ygpkQrj/tukiG5z3RQDAFxFUVWVwQ/nIrfZffCecFAJShY@CQ4hQRxBHBA4MBzwSUgJKt8EWSD9SGXjox8EhplZX1@XIlU5Ix@qRLpUirnnJX5Vzlve9yoxOV@U0dmk1ew@LhC/TOmvR3GOIMo4YPZJgv/u399gn0A26Ttzk5iSyDhZJ8KhbCUSsg7wq05CegE9EAn4lAC9ldRJhWbFElIyyZhaiaAfOzw8FEiQw4uKlAA21zMa2nEaYzweRyCGqibVZFJ8VfqSgyoMKvmKr7qOxKWBTKbr2TJ0lMoMnVi4V6NBDxgd3717B6VCS0pKB9A5ZWJ1iZ4tkCc48K3T/f7U3/WgZ4sS75gzLZ9lLEZXWsITZ3GJxdhGXOKLjzkS/hOL6oVClMIB9dXYhr/YKK8RO@DwZaSKiPoP7ywWcnHfc/eQ7R4@ebL39HRYrzPJpOtGzcbQdVqm58XQb@fpQ77/QC/m45FaDUGflnQUMNJeKU3i7@Dh8cFJifFMiyKIEWJlmiIS2SxqUmQ4fL4VEYstZLzbxpFP8F2a5S2mFzMQNVKVIi0TexTAS/gPv7L0xOs@cCbQ50/KclLLYzcuToO2TPq6M2Z48hrfpg11Cpejq1tbRAGpeqXQADoaobTyUrUqlikxTaqe7J1ChNNDpulpVap@wSYqJqhcS9V@pW/a3VFvHdf7yGdpOZSn9Vo6iX96JgNvLZtParnN@tpa/0rBNM@o2K5w4dY1WK8UzMZX4GHSVyT2FXCCB9LA1VhMLIU7OCyL9Uh4xkmML0qStRxUs7h0BgXNwUnD8FMeAntDrz70kyJr3/jGiFWr0JdWDvalCIiLHvPX5ChWW@2pVM7tsWuSb5extvW5hbcWqW3LG/aNKdQdIEfk@vq6A5AO9ple1cnKY7Txfd0ilyaYryeGFLFLpco7LbspZfVS6V1G1yVwkCIvXhhGtVpL16@ym3o2l83pmXw@t6kD0YrZfK6QSWvpfDqn61oxmy0WipvXLAYlaxhKtZLRM1JJrLTOZNISdfD//@fuh6YvtoZVIO5WaghGA4zZrZQBxiYYc1upJhgtMBa3UhYYx9WMlt5KjasSk7b4oWMM9zRX5JE5wTMOuZtc9cx@R8UdDRWZEtDlLXGIZ1XEq@LWEMdoV3DjKy7pj8WvpHal7bTo9jWprTad9lT1RtM@Lv3vO24lCopW1Pew8EJb3BhYqbG6OnSG0CDquc1ETUuDWMafVkjqybba6puGu50r5QpoCSZltnPp0qVlt51L9Ysnjx@NRsNjk3YXbGeLpbaKJ4vgGQDbhVIuV6/VZDlRo2TqeJkjr/PK2hrUE9NoK/DtOPbIU/RCHSK3LbdSiUa3M5quaKVMuiBdB9mXgHCYp6qEMROYlyQS70pUqpLt2FCBS0kjaV1RvkudTud64yoxs0jGlcJtQJFrxUg2rwJrWQmFK7FxUrFmnuBidKB9uRIzUiVZzxXkcq08s2/m5XL9Wro/MNuWgXsKztJXt2PlQdBxqBFI6IxJ1yXXcUalptlxXHMWMKPl/YAcodsBsvJ1kNxZGlO8up1cHgMBDTnlgFP5EW9VWkdXA6FQ34NaX6tv@Ye/IYfquqJnlIymaBn8v8Og4/@Hh9fhX8c3xMro0ilugH4KIhqaFZs9xo2UI4edOg7dKfjAbC0JsdszaMHgrut43j8gzAPDPudeDy1@6ljg9cjA@0S8gTXqLQnxbDjAvdOm@48GYW/QBASpYlOAB/By@46zKMAme3a0JJdPgnM@gRj8oE8Ifnzw6aPT0Pd0b2f3kZRnDw6fPrzxyYlAOfZ4b/80sG5yXz9qLgDx9b3Hj29axSd7@Oy4M3Zc/En7h8@ys1fghHvQpCw884ECZwIiXmglJQYHrNdYbtM3aBKuYr4HHbF7wpjLz4xpND7nG@wsL1hVy3dSlqRTf9edwVAANU3W4lvksWdIx9cIvVHbLErSkNnOJdtMs7bT7xt4R2tnDRx7Bu4mMlF56tNVwpj0peP225dW21yTnuDGpaKGF1EiEtIjADIYt@isCGiL8TC0Nt6eilMkzf7YZGO8oXiJI3zQCY2u1e1BA3Pp@AGkpmEwWjfzcQ/EN8PPaLXDiKdBbrd8@reDSxHJGBmRQvnePe3IhZpSTZdKXbO6NwE2Zc@g2hjuNFnIyWpL3mdqI9K1al59CCWVyWTz2gYqXqDtrp2lz0tZZ1g1PGiKEtka6IqjTqsMDVyuBCSuFrazu@mcKxcz8npKlh8Zf/1bP/m7P/m1Y1BhpY0UvCKaLOPy6TVNUkmp1ouFXKGY0QvJQrGQzWn5XC6p6Unoj2wWQSVNawUtX8gVtWQhW8wABxbBN1fclCJ8bVpqg0DCtwRg7RZelbhFernaAwWcT5KxNzEjziJGYB8z2YQ4soRdoBHtz9ywKtDUMC3NMpsMIBqsxSL7@7vp/X1ZfoAWXBWwm5blNlpyhXR684Esm@SzW0AFQnZ4nAIeOiOPuCWdfrAry2MOAM9rleUeWvbyOIgjyxZadnf29zGdDlp0jA/BzrkPt/R9yyYEs9ECiiQBeB1Ag2A7PJ0sIbqHFkwSffa5zy74yfKnPjroc8yDcQCP/Jzu7MjyAbfs7KDPLmU7xxH9DC079MiyCxaoDLLcBUPXhWooy00wYpWQ5RaYWlMD3PBaSjzS0x4Zsjzl5EECyfKEQhutc1lu@O6YzOcCmxxSt0QWjef6PlmK@CfLuo80BssElowsZwNLFvL26NHnRm/UNrv8mbr824KcPnqUMazJeG@/@emnzW636U539j49Rq/d3UfQ2k/HbrPbFBGbDXgciLX7SDfOB9ObD@T6oNEoGf2FXp81GlnDvuHVmDZMxBBivQbMxNPFhAaNXfDafdS4byyarySADZQGA/g28XkwgO8Do8m9/Ie86DtpNuUysj9qxnRnNdREuj46OTBarlNG@6Syxlg0Fk1Oa/l0vUwebAA6cLp8TZdVx/Bt4KBD/Gpam1TS9cqksqnzpS6dmHw20XOWnFwbbGvFXGnN2Nb0bGJSwr3fTifKooq2zWLavY03LPY0vq1nsiX5bHtbkWtafVvXCqX85ouNsSzHS/jezmyWIGA6Cj12fMVrm/XtzVwoyuZmwkjppc3NePka6DGC5r2JgwGNWOzSNM7jcUQXu6aQBX5V9pTyaZU7sUlyUuF4sWm8PKloZX6KHUvfgtXGI1PHrZHjcohdADfZTpfoMm5ZKxZkSD@VisXjIO9INMF3tv7t@ddOz09Pv5BQIFZFl/mI3/BaFtZPH@2q0IsWNjzqVN3HHojjqrsoruZ8@EmcvtMpqOnqI2hPoZPiu@F@HNfpq3uTljnEbozv4R9gp4pjx9TTR3NwTnrQ89gXfR@vTGfX2C2T4UmwVpsZlSqYjDaLEVbMiF9SS96oViuNyoDfp10NYn3G6JjUGZgDj@MebLKm6Fe4R0V4NCrp63KzMolMAE6jwhTt5cBpv9QTrXIbD4B9UHmAkcsN@DbLZsXEW8XliFzubNsVxsa2Z3TMI9PFIwMODtdBr8CNK7EOM@Pr7IzuIN9FZf5aqbrMnmH2dDyIQbe9GZ93ClmRNLGv@Vm@op1UuAbgutypsNiLePk1WN11FmurD@Lb2XI79oA14uCSftl52WE6y2fLdDNjDCFBJSLa0N3e8Ur1M1CFOODzUgkQEWV8DjAxJQBrtcnDiA@t63Kr0mcxhU1YnMiTLXcrNYz9Fl9biizXFaX2ti5VFeW5VIV6Wp5GjIo3btKp4Szd1PR0vjwBN20zW@5BwRovJmW3Mhy7ZrkPVjF@xDeMGWUgJ1ANwLx5G3v/i9@Mbym5CncrE6i3fdA@GmqjMinbeA4RsEQlUwGPRC2bTkInF16bSWjm9XxSyyczyWxS2URXaOOTuSQ4QkcHFItYPyYzJifTk7SqJTVTS8bSL632y3jyPAbaC5GMxZMjZw@vNAcXKCTkSrLC12DxhL7RZ1AKDjO2FGJTkBRlzBjQvMeGVrKHoI5No08x4nGFZTZi/fUYhlk/HQ/3avVSaW8y/Bp4xZTX2/nEZjrxJh4vx9biFVCCpGpZqqJUoVwP14BnxdAa88aDGpQxmLRNvVSrNTGLm@lkJp2B3FmNt90tuSrXk@m1vAZFdM1IPWJcYnAVaabkzNwaqH/3TSg5raiXJZUGkyhJLaYX9biECxJFTGkoxBpSksXOZH9zZCwa3dSj0Xi0jAPfa7IY6QRZRnIsCkI1ek/blkH/kktyUccAM5FI@9/SYRXsWsLBAZYtSpEr6frqegt6tylaHwi6JFsjk6JW70uREmOgB56JE1ZSa4x97LLDxFb1Bf@e4XpmgCvRiYGghNJyINPCLhn7HPf6brMoIGa4g5quZ@o1fRNaMpCOflBd18o42B/BFdNqFUjsXQF@W4kqbpP5jE2nRkLxR5/vMdZNrEuU6cjNCb2dyk73eKfs23ZxPPNMkmW5HJUjV9FI9Br@pMh92puj8705LBLanYMD2jhgDPR5FyHZwHav/JGnEt5bEzNKXBLU6vF3T63@VSGj8OEFEE3X15H1FJWI2OJQ/uylnoMysh1/zwN0iXAYBxqpXA4HYyOpl0PvG3oh8@Tg0H7o7puM73goZBtyNcLSmoI7CMol4ZqTG2vnGvBCRs6cJyPsfoRWPcvFgi7r3KEcYedKVCvxXRLDk@KLzReFF0@eHT473JciZ2tv1xwcd2c@mdg7@6tfg4DRTDbK2FklMqlky2JFWLWqaFs6nmW0yUog5jtaXkm/rXJ2rpJHXgef97/4w@xkqwB2Pa2BXddzCb1a1TZ0Fo8M33/5@3iIxdXe5zuPWdQzpuzv/uTH@ubf/cm/olVW0euyR6PEmxEIiUYtvxm5uhpeXV3Dw/1ykXqEI5XdjIOZzyZokWpK0zO2bZdZKWUYG5uJrH7fLqdEWG1Ti0c8JSLmRTZzEe@t8NLTBfDyJy7ISc5jkUT2jq2crt3fQibRgg1cLPjbMr0icEnhycu3jIGlVW13u5ZOplSKld4pbOudssXe4VzBO2WNvaxUca5Zw21f/lD6Bm5vwfmkaDWR2ogy6PWwau26XE8wGoyH/uIL09ywz26w@NkaKxZvOG3Y8GduePSHkXwHD6y@zdx45cmxjXgq1W6LI4@2TJarAitspACzs/j7X/wNXc//3Z/86tvG28YXOnQKi8W8pkd@rv385xBgxdEDfo@O5hzwjAA0BD1BtuSCc@jlShG89b7DeHi/X4g9QVQcrK4NvXu0SReo7FApNfh5Vu0YBdvAnclJUp3ptJl4WZICFZNUY7fbShIMtoH3T0C1la6kr6AXtKisApJU@soMFDgMoA11Wg2vP3aHtM8gRvG0epLdgyiQwlfwqLA12lEtxLECEiy1cTsqR9kjqpFixAam5@HBY9CSSF@BKOKsQLxW28DN/xjSskH@qxiE8CSPdg3SrkPafR6hQa4xyj0PkGQcOx7JBvVZ@gpoBEQFCxQFZm1BgDLInK8AASAPMQHYqrMtlomzKyuRKM9ONbvG5dt4BpvhbzyWMBpCa@NGdz9yGcOBE6jteDsV8oUoYdDRQo4@EA6DzwBXQPHH6GRDzYtOBvhgUACLTuGJUdbYvXszrCoVqx1nlCOEf24NcQyLysFejCsA8ztNn7RLcpLheXFl3zVgO6B4gtAFrlP4QXHlUFQmo/VakuD/g5kWOfJGUZFHGTMgyovXihaQDCIj2XkZtthWhWn6ZpwFyLcA9xYhRWeUBT3Bs8knqv6F73kNGP484p/9DoLoNDwuKPj25s5zBi3iGA/exvOHuDAQO8b5CUMo0A5GfuwgFmTF6lPojuVCL4Wmpv3jymIZLY7RZse7ER60KFvPMlwbnYvjh2JhaAZfAw/mEums0eEiLQcK1Bs6Np3kRaeO4Lpz4AiQUeJAJI722L7EixpE2VDkMEYeHYaEnI8Y08lkdMMlxcW54aYLXVmfNklmdlXWGrSZXmQxYjQ6uMkOwMUpEiHcBJUXadzsmwNA6cQ0aT@QV0qluqAwjZt0etUTC/iqt29Bq2J7KXGZaOrSOrdSp3jQtOJ0cNsQPwsggjoWVj8@DS1Oiuo7zjnrW@cmH@6NzZ2k4DFQ@kFxTQJlZz8gbAnXN@iZJEuDd5KHgt8mfDa5sZAMxV2LTeO3vxltLdbAEn1LjYzl4kWhF4Ydoi89byXRz/Wmnn8WC50oAnY1ELmmOIWhEsX91cHxIpI4VaZCB5qoOI0wjEGv0z@NBY2gj5sXDHusErYxIDRb/rkGWIsht1@hBoDqHtQsPJht5JbwNA7AxG3HWlD1hIC32Scso0sYkB@VI461ARhY9JV56OAHUTEf3qgNBaPyHWwgV6B2Dtrgh/vABfthfJ@70UyH5s3Ym60JcNjoUFoVxquFb8mFLFg7kJ8p62vgmQcMF2CyFpMTADYhx2UOOoh/MzrndolkSYndhpRkCEGQGqCQquDfJMxCNypI4PHA8Pixu@IIt8vLS5XOEhy7lmp6eMuAh9cjp4ZdC9RlJzUyB0Nxn5uF93gKuDOTwi8XwUuztyd0XXXx3pR/JanjVcQqkVi040WxcbzAQ/S7AzqDCA//8Yih9i26gKMVE4tWOP/p9eSVz38l5D@lEL1GIIwhmElymmwlAViy2TpPdi7bZeFxQRUSgEMpmr4jnt/p@paB55usYScI4Yxok4dvb/bPaUoUIMl8XHaWNM@hH3LqW4V9aE0gkm1esh3XNaYx8o9jaGTg2JTUHjaFZp98wAjNDLvih0lak9q0Phd9EkSHRs3vDTEXDxiSrlYD5SeLov@E@0/Af8L9J7NE/WRrkzpXydDpGrODXI/n0vkhEczUD3PNT@Gc@RBk0LGZxkFgyOmc2zX8WhWK7dOb26AcKz5jAE8MgeBmLFV7cVY7q9ueeblRT6S6wOwyEQJKHEDX6kTTy3ZgRur3L/pDx5tzsvE4QmiVBN7o1OoJbuC8gnkMCogYg9PLwhPkugOxlIArBCLDAAH1MPBE1WBnFLPi5eAkW/IExqnJMxpzxGoCmTppX8JLuIG6xEnPCRsGVA8BQvcgS4Am@DC/5vA7ZXzp8Nx1IIwfVqFrMAZ4klG0HgVK3qgqXNaUqZBCWCmKjyaQHdXVys2s@P5QFLUbXqFsXovyD6O/9tHod6BeLMaeGJY3GGUpXFVwSRyoEKK6EFVZtRIqV8AgtWH0TRdarj2un4rWGpLZSPndDJ4OZsG7xItyY6HCb8V5@dC@O9mWSwErTCsVyOK0wqslrxc@STnBg2ieiDb1GUHE5wIEYKQXRjNFtEk42qRS4YKDTZZEuwwhOSEkJzwKDz1ZgmRdRIPeU3DDOhZPHbRTXLMnAzyNN6OgBg1lhrfl4sz2KzxlDSdARZozmUNcIHgIVWzks1Z9Yeq1ENIhoXUDADLiLQBtfj1dSbop8DQlsAUyipPSl1HcJtiAywpgMBLBZX4SaSxgMuoDg8IvJ6gdgLorJ2qSrNHgLv6l@U9O@o7@T7vtmJ4Pqc07ppM3/v5RHOtI2VAFDWkfWjqLAhl7Ms9scYRfWOeI4E2uPQe0uualw2ILlG1wT41F1FSz7zRTAwNXqOClVeIi5@E07vcfcGKE3R86I2PkZLMl3mmyiO0Wpc/7DFbXdvCs@9AJxKDrtR3Ts6MjKNSW07Utz0wyPCju3BTdDlMcfi6F9WRhdDxJEsOTvBuLoDlfoarbaOA1mo1GDNfXxUvB2l1abofsGY1K2P8FUyg@iCcB9HAYc5qvzNYofjdMPCxbRDu1Wuexw6HwjEIiOwxkWAv0f/DtgQbDPGfWc6Rje1GVbo5idOB7zxk4XdD6xp4qYewb4A9msBEhYzgkXJLMwC5tKXRkOtWSWCtpxEXUzz46KvtMjxnxIL4@D2COGEnm3qQxUtZdkFxjaXI8mp/eycfjexLG92Q1vtQLv4kz75pXuOfHJZ2JzSBAwBkambvRwKyD3GrfQmcOlcAZ9Soe4YNRbNMKsDZiugNBd0RwtQP8kQxsHtgCxD9fRv/VBehH3/vQ4jPwbuGTKcibAS5MjNH1JJ4/wxmD4AfxuBRZkFzA2g8/MC0IizdD7aMKAWosCS4bTxyFijmEbrcXnIPvA76D53HR1S2@p5VYFe65ACf3IsnO9eVF9LDRNvvG1GzHRMhkCK6f42PosJG8@rCMo6Ajoefwvl4M2q544AvNOBKdByotYRkjeRGPL2crHsQKuIdGygnDg@X0Q/9bohmH@Cp8tBr6AdFoBIdjLywc/hxOh1N@qHWf3yoj5Chvf3hJ4uECdxME6CBO1EnOko2vEp/HsSBLH9AiBGHV@SzjmbM@RDz15nYZfhyJ7s4pFG4oUsUvZWn@gobFJW6tKvEQV/g8yaeQPowl72K6D@a5EKtxYDMRtvtxTcgtyLgoo9WKhSFyl5Ul5ti3ZAK60TidvaRVaSwQqEFMknQji7rbpF/EJewZH8AXB5w@hy8C7JqjBmcoP284piWue2LkMzCGIa1FuICSDlBCVOQkF2iEQkm@GYJfXQdptpam2bqVZmsuzaAGzCcZCiS15pIUpYDFs6oI@mZntEQ6oxf2neGzSmzDYzuGi6MVV1ErWrKSLHoRLYFAjprR0l4MhHK0HS09JIMXLZ2Q4Txa@gwMs7oVfRst@dUCA7hgJcN9dBciHO2taGk3Fr@WRsa56fnpqtFSUKYQZptbiSJACsw3aI04xWY7Ipsj14SGjZTKJEOO8ZLYfaJxmCT90vDPr1yhqxvQE8c4NygwSzBtrtEItRg8HWg2/KPBF9TkkmjN9w73aVFTEASTSUAfLxyHwIMaHonOCyOOGPrSjAZ8AUGUm6XFGLFQS/aB6IjUgUOpkOfTJ@qppA@0Y@Rfg8D1WSJ0z46I75fXPAhegB@GJ0ZehuctdPzkCCOck40vQAuJ@jK6IlNY1vO4iNIPlxCNdc8Hwsu5/SC8lAhsSKaDDkeTc5jY0BnOMwn54jp6KxyHBuV4pUTuvRGNpIKomUu8yVnkDAVDuPLHV2UnFA9RmxNB6FlL13ktC9oFksXoNZN1IU2VVz5AISRzoIabrXO6w@ihMFI4Lm6S1FYsa4b8uDxJklzzYhIiq3hK0tgY8dSDzusenp30cd1XP@YEx1piCCAUM0iFy1fnI/R3h@vvvkLtE@FGAosU68VN6W31emUrewPz/izZ2wWInkn2ML5QOQpSmJEcegchzXwVr91S8XHJB1fyeaIB9Bvavk@2oE9wB91u9i04LNQS3It5x3MdHM/15YS6rZH0L1RfaVExJQGHZzzAdJa11bjyjC8qYvSh8W2j/9EF7M4XcLjwEB5lwL1Bcl7L3bFNq1xmdRvENndBkaqVGBfkNF0aFPPMEcQ9Td0G07bgcNg4fnj49PHXodHd3NyMizZ6OsMPay2OtQbtOIdMK6SD9mBBt0VP4rUkONmNw/Fez3FHa2e2fEuWcGENyoABqfjsJ@p4XMiykDy/UXchHg8boqiAdT6rBsacVEJVx8Am2xJ0HQFBzFFswxBAfPUW6J2k3lqcLuBoNPDy80aDmq9GAxcvNRqiFcOi8WfE4z@PrKXGnkvXRfLbYy4liU4lYA8P2fNHO6fs9NEe23@2@xn7@uEz9nzn6SluSD969uDxwS6D397Tkz0mza2cxJu2sEMJdH1otky8EBGPmMsygrzrDKdc7sR249z9xBiwR07LxGmqLc8Y3O9xi2qboyqPtQfd0SmOYVp0m9rAGuF6C7oKDLqxqNy0ae8fLuhnELYJfdoB9nkHTtvqWBBWwr7v0DI9f7sY61tQgiBv/b2/Sa4k4a1ftHSI7ufDFViXEN2A8Dh3A2AMvv6K7pe3PB7BbKtMEC54PpqCp3vHT04Ynm2we/j04cHpweHTE7Z/eAzWo68fPP0U6Hlwcnp88OAZelHAJ4cPD/YPdnfIgSOQVhkeOvBq7I1WoqBicKJK6xxnvtUhFH9gmx/1Rg2eXRq0C9Jj0bGN0scy@tYbsx0tS2MP1RfceUlTBSy2vnP86efQ5jPzNc5w@lPBtP5AfubR7XPrabZFqUFlqUJ9K4vqCs2eosVpPmIwZXgZhVmmwwhiZE4yHzgt4mlbJpN3cY0Kjn3zMwuoLvugIaE1gI2g/AUrFUaXyESjyS0CWYXUWn0Hz5fkqfFFhMKCUe/7S03KElFMrJVBoLhp4cDG8SCtHDgA34ODLpIduTwAywQOPADLcgdURQ9w7QjLiRDj0eEYxTPLc4dXg@E@TQv/P8U97VYbO5K/6adQ2iR0Q/uLBEIwJjFgEs8SyPCR3BxDnMZum55rbF@3ATuBe2b3x77A7v99hH2VeYf5tU@xWx@SWt02hDvZcybnBHe3pFKpVCpJpaqSeKk/bPm0i12TOHG/UZf6Ql/ChREcunRVEGt56ApDP2qGIRWJKD9eo9Pt8sAI@AI3kIl8lEi2bZDTBmHTxqMGafbGN51iKnAD2gn57VEknLKbE8doHBT0Qr6kqdP1e2wCFZvuEO@JNQyWU96Uywd9uRG5gQz6xIB4sVoSD11uR64Kg8eWg5JbUzX60kaSLhhUJmg/QmBrCoF/BAwAyiZ2Ok2aqcgxFcH025KVnagPHIl629/N/MDOratmkCggrbacv4TfvrmSyF5in6TsFAk76KJvwRCWlXSU2e4PYYyTWKXrYFAKNi/6g1HIfegkW0AnTjTNQW6c2KC2r4q4sjakQ7rGXr9nVHoOXHxPrefAlI@plTiez861@IrvBgXOh0mY7e4QHf@8fx0YZ2ceHiLdBKh@gYUwnZWj8nMyIkx4/WnFsuN3gdcLrpU3d7ZOs79/9fCOQRYLfK2nMjrE/8CYWBcMDzrnI4PFIa675EhTd0NFV@dYWtrgSWmJo1wBg33gRQj7ujeNkk5jc@Pp7@gok/5OH29vy1wqi5JJ3vQaXTixdPNEXVXpUZkzIU1ADNkJyIKsd9QXj2Bqef0GnWOwF0pAkR7KEdy3p25ekiJEte78qg2SRV6AKbtbw3fFJllUxPcBo9OL2R/5L85WeWnTzccGJcIgp6NEtKcgF13XMEuh@WoK3M7D4EB@Px7c2oPY8fTwh6DtPAjtD@GWXbofFk9LBqzHg/39AbA8uf1DYKHt3v2AeZKchqY5XTOnN5/R1rQP1/h1qu9o7AEYnHtRg6KBGrVd9eiIWoVzdriAa4KJF0RHxzvVw0Nh8/4EyoLcwy1DS4pBhP1EfIitbcMeCbucXjTpzbJePKkvCYs29e@hwTyTePeICrkG8SQ9tLCIb75uh2OWenJmoSUEWd@TQFSUS2L3XcmgqC4B38EeEJCNO81ooDWzmRmefMLINAKXdPN4bWza8JOFNc/deK3kcGICMm2C/A56lszuv0@8Pl5X9fACC6P7YINbsJKG@Qb2CUdQ8QAy5nLJHnygW1SXopE9L7AzinZo@FVIrrB/nqGIkXgRzmthQ6zLxbFEjdfH82qZQwaJOA34aOkpE9miGRKUiKcvG2aHuvGk5ySnIFhk4kWDb0yugOJnd3IKI2roebKsF@TmWJsnbOoKyzPUzkrYpfszPUVb6NW0eEhXBdL2waqy/z9V8SyRqEnRfGZjVCJAXl1Zef4j2OlWqOLZn4XNc0hafo4uB7C/j0FGk4jU@8C5tX1PpccM8ADp2LReDZhUQVjqzJhTEm2nycjED3BhvRAgg7HN8e7GdK2uGKdwmw2dZyQTOmWZaoMxhHVDedRMUf/u4epQIP@wvid/vD4ebJgJTQfv0Cr/fX8YBbFXnhGgxfiErq3Jb8Fw2KNs7M90iVAccmN60NmOvO3Y4JVbhYl03ma2pC29k9js1lO6BqqE1Is5vK4VtXultHovWyyZTd2t7VXFIsU8bCd0kfbQdg3Z8yTsPYQAyWDSS@D0QT58T6N1@A84eAokkIm8@RyijftD3IgisGqu06020ixUytZiuvfbUdPvYVwPz34aCdt7BgVJC1s92HVnadYLpUR5QC4a9Bwo5dnZnE1F4RsqdBFSEgT3Jn43Jiz01FCWkuhe0@mjfRQebAVj1p6R5aSfL64VVl9Z1LqeN/Iu66/OvMVm2RYw@fq9y@hqeNP6tdO/uG6Lrhj85XzcnHz7TYiVF@I53s75jAPPFlfLeYr1@RL@rolXBeJcieBrCqJ7aguR44v9hFgQ8T689ETwpXa0aV5HD4kUl4rFS8WF6GI3Kl/WV8/KvXKhdFnvnZXQyW@0VB4tFZcc/PAMZlGQMXwyXx@d4Zxqal2D3rXA@17pXj7pGiLINQS@vPeHYX@vsv82oY3DBQCqwKStNynU@arWObRmQ9@TXC@4caSazBPIsRYukKw58goqors76ZNRHdMKATPoFQ9Ws9GY/k5ca66QuxqM@pSi4g4ia4nb8NaaU25MBdIoQJZ6qKIT0g310TjO4@DBEH@dsBV1tsjLtSL6TroGiDqWJHFon9o2@hQiotKXq35mRbnAb14gEng38S0VExsbdFMxsFqUIy0emnL4Q3KYKJzhIx6AwM@AThuwClq5R@T2YUHz8b2ID/yFdFQj8pMhA3mLVoqYgubf4jv5N1H5DSAAE36O11w5qeKUKy9YSLLvICkXMHpZcuOPxwzoVsmdMoeNRdhcXzkGTpbiRCOsVpIJvs/dIDmZVvBPtiBbpLepZuj8LmcnktA5tXyLkJbUpZS0iT/duJhjFMuqYiqzQYq5H1IDNV2wPXofwLCaiO2g2wWkmRZzMTnwkfx7Zf1Luv6ojnWeaeQ5PTuVnk2k5zidkYpz5WCCjzOtm5nszPc4352w42zeVF1lQYuXHPR0MwdLkjhv6aG8UW7Ub4Rx5k3dlcyVOmEjkZA1Ur7M6H1OeZIooxlcp9c5XfL3sux5jWUi75tk/fhryQ4KyHhW2pqkuDTXC7uvLXmtrUxBNrOBmkJwcexvYjselNIHU4oTWMGhnp@G7WY5hrJUVBKHxoy9ufHGzslFxmsnjQZ7MU4NrBljxKAS1blEhBuTwyLUQ8lPDBAEExlNqJG7qQpPZOGJARZzPVHVshfk1ACHpqWHeBn9Im/xjxrsSeRUvszsxDnGfMyNZ@/mJIFI6D6xZ5MpKU3QXYQ/ykY9MIvEdU/SEGcLiX1DC6zrDNgHu41q8CdaTpiCQkmKKbrrFEnpOENRse99XYiJd9b/5hettz6ssQfdYCwquM3wyQvLSji4j4JoFGGAJwpTE10NBl08daQF3w25UMuYIcsreNwSQzRm9pxVQ8sezu/hk3RIh0I5cYCQb9BAJE6IrjoddCZDD9j@DYpW1LiEo5xV6U1YoQFj5vkyu5kH4iriU1PY7XdMJLjnePQgpaOB3wxyFqzRIlj9WNzUdijvlCR9OvqNYAgxmNLWLevPV2Hz1@23eJ77slh4XjRIdi2Pgwu55y9iBysgkkpYxvB/K8UXlmWcDTf5bDiLAD2xhxP9R@DN4Dro9QKrAjMGZYxg0RoFw@uglbOsw0AfAiNcZGU8mUQ/7P7VsMnKHVh0@cCM6CUceXwcBhyGvzg/83Fxk87KPAsPreLTZujq67CFBFQeJ@0@ng7TgQWGCWB6YKHLYAREWXRFEiU6e5a40NrlEhVRQA2Mc2KcTWgy9PqjsAk9Q5osqwug@BgkrqzXSmEC9TW7PjoH52YhgO4xMQUUAuoo6SEcLHlo/odwELJh6ozdVz2TB@nXp7ECwz0YhiB9YwJTr1AxA3fo4ON3tSNxdLB7/KlyWBXw/OHw4GNtp7ojtj7TGTcelFNoXfHuYA@kiz5N51PzA/hgV46gpE0JVmX/s6j@8uGwenQkDg5F7f2HvRpAA/CHlf3jWvXIE7X97b2THTp9Bwhi/@BY7NXe144h2/GBR7WqYlZcThzsivfVw@138FrZqu3Vjj9Tjbu1432sDE/1K@JD5fC4tn2yVzkUH04OPxwcVQU2zNqpHW3vVWrvqzs5qB/qFNWP1f1jcfSusreXaujBp/3qoSAjAaOVW1XAsrIFW1isidq5Uzusbh9jg@KnbSAeILjniaMP1e0aPlR/qUJzKoefPQn0qPrnE8gEiWKn8r7yFhpnOT@gCvTL9slhFUMhISWOTraOjmvHJ8dV8fbgYIdofVQ9/Fjbrh6VhLV3cEQEOzmqegKv3qOqAQZQC9LheevkqEZ0q@0fw5xx8gHtHVzo5E9AGMCyAkV3iMBoBoGtBSIdHH5GqEgH6gBPfHpXhe@HSFOiVgWpgBYV28dmNqgQiHhsNlPsV9/u1d5W97ermHyAYD7VjqoudFjtCDPU0CDjM7AOVHpCrcZ@Arz4EZjVUpzrUXeK2q6o7HysIeYyN3DAUU1yC5Ft@52keQ4D7RpKlLCPOgP/0lSstKc/XQcYYXJaIzNbR6MjJm0f7FRhRpZxq@w44QRmnbVUKCUzDWYanQiviZA1reD8qtMIe@0@@pjqYqz4uIw6Ht4y4@IVHafWA5csSf0KFchkGo2PlQZsdI8aDdd7TMkEGj8qIdXgD@VyZRvxTgHceaPiZ32d6b6RINTmM3nQSYZ6eACBOZn6z9j0zb8MXJHPtwJZDJ33EbBSHUV8bHKBRykgGsnZEe8WiaskzQS9h5IdqKCjwOeaDdSTomUkZepH8Kd3G7/w5GB8AOnM6q58HjexhEb4LVDVcCUUEoH@yIgEYZuqzEVB8GvHKZjV4Z4/1@n3W47rqjKUdwT7wI7j/qD4edBJFc@myxOydOwsQ/lHat9NSxh9/ixJJmS/5IbUMgf/NEb04ypsOOYDak2pKlJWS6Wl84yLo0WSJ2RoC3SvoE7GNd/7yi@1T7ibKyy/KKW@v9PfeWyhvSBGooUJr07lzujn3RlngAFGsTiAJKGMkJHPG2WUvYnOfAMZLzDTTdhCyx@Yqy8CmteBJLCQvfK7Zp04Gw/DsYk9yOG3h5X3Wye7uyA6EdsXaysvV0uWDrv1i8e/n7EeChdLUccGMI/DOo2SjFGyDQsfGilGmO6Y/YmB83nMiCHZVafRR4zzoO02kpZMKMiwuRFetNNDEz07QDrYggJwPLEUv84cmZIBnERTXWzNpT@mJb4PayXiAWnM0p1Qr43xD8LWw18Ncd0gyUCSxSiALnAu7C5I7tm7ylSUNjcUuAez5GzFxxzGTdOAVF1kP4vetfQmedvoxYhNGXG8UrdTSUDiSRoLoewqejyyP1CcEakApuhh8OUXyW/w@FkGuKNwd340qoyOgIy7uiTqqWNltGx0XUI@wztzMKiaqmlDoJbflUjR2JPqZB0YxBgNhApeg4I2vknAJR1HJF0lWcC@WXDFd@ZUDN6BcEqSY@U7cO6s5kgoJRU/RL6rqBSCYekgJ0y1G12HpbJ81nEsFDkTZPopehD8fyJNZsDfgB0nQI@pZQQBfBQlCSrTCravRJTwRh00GKcbMTXNT59jMHdmx1zohsnTmzH71wAJZO9M1IfPFPaw7cwgADI5KjbM8atN0i582Dq9sV1ZHM9Jes3LgSPkXKGmiim42dUzj5ZdnjpbwRdXuKxrMircg6LiDW/czmnUw5YptZUXTyObwbkq/kd@kRQgesATl16w1WqaswpylCk5IEMtGRNOS0dMgmXp3b2ndovCCJGZkP3y5EsRCkBvIj7T7aS7QvqCzXOTERdpJhbHFAUPg4LjNhknHxmy7pwMMbsBwnnaImUIXicyusEJosvQKVRfDE04T8lQBCuJrQ7jOIMobt0ckJam1RuNPWkmkUM19ic9jkYfsFZL5chxgA@JoekunxPv/Qmg3H1cs5nF8otHfQ9tF7EyVkvI8nh1SrPfH8LS0cd2A45eOHFz4pNUOgS96Goo4xfCfBYOpUZCLfqhGlw28e6dphkOBE@oReEIvRVaOeIPatJlgBaiHJ5knF0VDjCv4tFNpXQMx0tF4WzEKRtAEwpLSkTcEKvi9pZzMUFlyNCAKBhGenNBNptUD5476OF30x/@inM/LoF6raClI5MaIEkXyJ1U61GMx@aImz7oR6TRgK5ADYimRJEVadpQFebol5KdpF2THUfHxNil1JI/Xo9mUmUtBRXFjCtrB@ZbzUJnIpWWZWhQHSy0uLxCqMzacN3duxmjaKHJY2thn/a0SFnnRUT5qVo64hPLTf30GZ@kkr/8NMLRA1/wjFsuQRFhXLPiueq0nCP80KbgUxgMW6ZOFFYyLX@A6jfa@vR7xItKdSjD/jX9URRMYAfQzIfjPMFoOH/qX/Qa2/2u3wn7oQ/7NIzlPmaJh48TesQO6wz7NxHdCkQJLSNTaxI/c3wZDsOG7/pcsmSE5opGwcAxzRRGw0nlgsNEkOYcjQDj2y@JvwfpGGm6zIuVuJCV9D8le7yiW7q37PPirMJ8oo8ApIDbTFlQsA/piByTDOfT0lSG84cyGDiei6zw3Xss9hIYvwIS0TFMAmOFzJRZgtkI3Jndi3G9NfZaFINwiIGWgp0A77OJHPrs@XihMEiR12gpsC6KawWjKJ@ijDEOIT5M7if38st/MvaAwE@gX3w@i1tmMQKJuLaKthTxfkVGGQVcyDwwJBlNkhikWNiBWaibANoYp6Emkyf3UYMsf2BRJMPsTXEljkgHNj54eZ3TAJHTmLg4qSyIBZfiduASpDJyCvczbPAj@1ka/HiIy5ozFEzbErJjIH0fqZpAJbyyNWVea6LMMZV/PGKWlx/baykClmeZnBlXBzu2WrmQB0rI8ysea/WHIIztFPWkqcdCNOoPFh5JvXtlx8zIbLNo3XTdHxoCM7OVYbJcbBFpyxN8nJSsND4ppklSjCzNgIdw@0rPms3TRByXGzjeyo3JD@hwH81iuyk9qej@bvHYx0nxGi161USjhxThjkFKS/p7vQENb9wvQSRM3l41SGI0UGQ0JvxogEqRSVPp8RQi7pO4p@jRAsphvS2gndk/9xI1bSSnQp6qpESQS6QnBm5Hp02QS4M2Gl9gmDhe4WohpRecY29CR3nF7DkGGcYEBoir4iAb66FYgxt3VoqP6HaAttNAa6EiSiJ42jQtHHTQf00wisovlTvS4qExyRbPSgxprCHBroJyPQRJ@ZvDa70xJihTpIAhPoMUukVTsuni8a362bZAPoDApSlZWvoWPGyMK5YAG/hjJjXGuAaOq5IlEyMqORAaJBpgLMAupdMNeLuKq79wyByP1g1yGMEGgj87@LMkS2A479WCpjYWGbcmmMWV5ObR5orsJheJGYrfkfxyKPJSlzauACBgjKF8uQgQMKwpYY@HAhR6x@S8BKKyj6BguYjDEj5SVNTYznNGOhJVZnixYuQozMrxyoSRnQkEFhaz88SIwJpldpYYCkx0M3Excryc3Z44ByyIFe8zxaErZK8kaah7jglI1yoX3Fii1IvCK0gOpsQXK24iUfM3pb4qGKmFdCrQR2NYzxbTqWuFRGqi2uXlZNFESaCHa9aaSARSuCbCWir83D9yTTFDnmubUGOTkVhlSPtsvPYadpmwb8v9JRIb5JSt1hgKnukZrrZfDb5iJRGU/eEA7GKBjgwwdvtPt1ZZpipM5F0BFJdOObs4vCGkFauNUz02C3e6KtKeDlCg9rT9tvh4vLubCPt6PlGGRpfBcKVQKCATn5vB75VtNaqSwn4@mTvfvup284ObPw0/nudJ9gcBXQmwrnbQAXQJDIoo1x92@GYIxAGyYu6sdGTFvf5Vu21ewYAnlNh50G2cU0ZDEDQBhdro5eMxKYAIpJxgv2IDsX1fhR59Nz4vNCUUdQwFpdEk@NpWp2dAHvzQRvtsfVJFwFAwK2smmLfc8uZ3nEHwZhPqLApf7H6PzZPtd0G32/fEJ7xXGCMFzN2lC@zumgUKnAVPGMm79yqieLSeCK7DruFXjFlMXkdwamJS90youPAYG/8w6FTHA8euf7FhWoEmL2EzlzA@tSfsju3KYPGPAMt8CGg/KvelP3CaRKd0Zpjq5QiOnwCj50Vv5t4nkcUlnZik2Y9zI1Fno5ujYA3QdJfWAiqWPXUvteSe7Jq49um42EYaFhiGxAljrjyuBLqa/fPE4vWo3X6cVKRrALhj/5BE5JtQfk4g0hkAjUA5/ICeGEX7X7IwrHdTAUV4gYOXdUzLHSzQwAKW9bRZ/u3GqVQqYn6wtCQqlS14yGZFZasidvDD1pbYgfctfH9WXl5ZKbHM3XG/w8ct9fFObAEM0nAuNS@GO/AKaWX0G0Nrbezi@Xx53ivNN8obm6UoX69soVs/PP39X//97//2H/mKfPkvfNmil/oXnSmXy@Xnm9/nn92V8L2@c7Ywf16fH5wtdErIZf9LUcP7tVHWj81Hc8NzK8OzgPGV7EjVPpuiz8iiQl34d@kPfwXpsi4yzSifkV8jvjmKZGymGRjfA/SjPIctvLp0IL2VByQyAHSC6njonWaABngw3wAlARe0A@XyfLaiFPcYDkZn0KcqGRmJh9as1wH6tMSRFNAXF2asbNiLgh5qwK9pzcvNsywffsNRQ/Jv/sv7qLPVH4vFU0csFsSiJxZtm36Kq6/gqzufD9E7l7PBdsC2PUiJjxbQzFBEIS30aP9Ad@2kyG1Z83RlD0JSYSooM3vBeXr3R84yfOFa1LHm8D5NwSoSOmTCIpnv87076JbvkOPOTrja0EKhIXcxVJlxoqL7F5dAfsSGAHHNl0yQ9T5UiSd95JGMT3n1Rfa1RbcJEWAk6@HbXRr3@AHmovmetHlO7KXwmiMyn@evODeW2Bma0MYUrj9GgA5UeDtZIE/ChcyCxVbeRiupmeyFbbZPMh/bOkyCkbJN50K/C4MJ2JrbJNx8T/q1SENuPl4RdqiPV4yq7LTtt7CMIpdX3VE4kO4KVDsOqO@6tjseSdijBIjhcMz@9ekRRooCFSkq1S18WdZEtPrYdB4JPemaDh3s5vjkyCBC/osDY/s2NbbdPHmJKHZgHiCktClf2w@7kYy6MiRid/zhOd4O6LfpQrURn5uRPg9vUE1h3G9rpHMEmUzO4/EMTckMhn7n0vdEZr9/PPQnNZi2YOUzauZcaCGGYEIkcPDJqmc1TyHMLZJdQhTRTSHLIby8oDuR16Nx39ra5wS7VA0FGXYFB0GCnYiSwW2ir1J0jLn6D3SCifKU8NankVLEkuRFSyMJyTbdZmiYTQ0dS9Vgjh09cGyLUdUjU/GCLHSFE@0lHfyCJO9ijABZty29AKUrwuorrB9np07Q8xOT06BrKUf/fEnwvIjjma6iZGskS12CWoxvvEOsYB35JRkFgucmFc7ImnOcudNIXueWMecRCvKtbfHzvgj1BXR0gRl5hoiTXsjCMjVDxXdg5ESNLP8BQrvrdwC/yY0/QVY8zTivn@Td@pfT3tmic9q7Pf3mEiZSJKtZNisy8jBbSSw5VmBmzHuJV2WVFqlQg6e9ZIbTnmAfFoMEgEjeqX/Jn93mAaHTDF4sf5phgiS6DDHJP1xfHsHnp9DMJLHIZ6w5d9FVne@8LroC5lb6xT7kDy7/AhZqU0lqetjnDNsAivx0f7til5Mov7ZceLFcfAE7oU4wzg6DK5xvs9HVeTCGpUSE21mYek6/JbghQYi7ceSX4OMY2snXmrDvSSSdlKQIlcOc6rE0W0GZHPME5AcqU7hUdHFxdR4fDx9xw@8JYDmVl2JBsemgwX0Ozp9R/xLr8SOUa2nvEOZItDJgGxFSoWYRsrp85T4OddVwWSA/p5zYxtitBAS6N58xZotev5eVizU3t1DCRTR6zXTXCmuF9BidGqKJETovF1MLT0Rx8/XLv/3nwW@ZUWZzOf9pCL@jzG@Z1bUMP8IDvD1Xb9eZzcwGZlu9y0zysAeGx5d/@28ov/kngIMpkw34s7miYK1OMpvZMhW5zWyuwkNxeRnq/Z@//hXaMM87NryLdb7hCUKspCiy7feIdyFd1LCVvC1diMUKOWYhDLYwhL05vKBh1Hh5rUBquoy0qrgOZOQrZY8ip3gyzBqRqRBrMpQ9BayMuEAZK8gySGVC0RaG7YYy20DmjdEUX5/mViPYAXyV5hy6Sm268TRCk6F53hZBBzpcI@zn@WGz8NrW5h3rtrIpKaklJG7tpKxde176Pw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/dzwo0)

I tested it on Windows 10 64-bit.
Command line: `cmd /q /c polyglot.bat 2> nul`

`&` separates several commands on a single line, like `;` in bash.
`:` at the start of a line creates a label.
`&:` causes cmd.exe to ignore the rest of the line, I use it on line 2 to fix fatal error.
`goto label` is used to skip lines until main code, see line 3: `n&goto e` (`n` and `e` are for ETA).

Main code:

```
:e
echo 330
exit
```

Answer (score 4):

## 333. [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 14932 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@     <!--    (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####&:#######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//      n&goto e 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnn n M n M M M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
:e
echo 330
exit

*/
#1""/*
333
quit

































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Pr"93"s>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461!\0k:4op>astdequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05在ｕ/a>""Ha 892
 
*/
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwIf4EKlSqaRb6ltVqpZUt25fisUCSZDEFQiwAFIiS1JFd89ur9v2zHp62o522@Pb7hnPttcTMd6JnXV7x56JsPfjhGM@@QeUHxsbjg33P@g95yQAghJJVfkRsbGxkAjk82TmyZMnz8lnS/f6P/tZDB/2zLGmPcsZsZHhjVjHNc8NV2YPpuy@bnp5LSsIGGrH7Y0Hhj3yykKMqYx5I90dMUu3e2O9Z7AYuGpsZu@a1shw08wzDNYyLOcC/LOM2cYFO7DbZgcgsZFzZtjmG8MFvxxjDw3ranA1Ym1nMNDtjseGrmmPyDfP2DMdLN1x@4zpLW/k6u2R6djgVWDsuW3pg1ZHZxR86Bo80iYDUO0zijPvU2TsieN6BqTgtA3Pc9CxBI66azqPd55@fCO8mmEf65CpoWVMbiSvquyFabidmzE09unJ/v5N1yz7RHJstn87S2qO7YxHzsHoJvw82@kZts40uSRrNz0LgMyRYRUzxcycF/jtmy7Upu7XWnlWM/Z40DJcQL5fhRfmqC9DhBOHI5w5tjVlxgSAQR67EMwYMRNri@UzGQwJ/8dG27E7M/DgZAAcgGsMhqMpk5jt@DQAXo7LvKHeNqSOYZkDc2R0mGVC7pyunxuPQYWzM2N64bhQ8RInRcqINzTaZtfEKH4JPAGJ7aHRGveYMx4Nx5A9j3VMT29ZEKw1ZR2jq4@tUZq1wA@QR@4XfcP2s2TaPSzHi5kLQrChCfDcr6uAG9OyGGTnDLODSXtsCz0u0B2DtgzKpdFBUHszdAEk3fKC0s8nPJcMxnvmOj1XHwChdgzCwacHz5jXdlywwQ/D8lawCkxbH7GtLRbfe/owzmohGmW3JYQorbJLxlgs8GTnujU2PDbQp5C2PYLGxRyqvyCGAMFZfC1eZvFslmkZlsuxHDS2ItPyGQZNogQGaLVaVoVfgWlFllOB7vPxNKbTdfWeaRkcSs@xughoEylWyzMN3pkcy6rFeJqHaFM6myxbZIVNtplnm/AusZIGCSHUHFNLefgV4AdQSpALFX7ZHE8tJA0kKSgG22VdfWBaUw59OETwbZZX2SZAhKyqAFkrAoSShhDmnyi8UR@Q29fPAaRkmWfIMoyQa2CNKfBRNjYUYlvIH3mSXt@wLEwVkAVoyhfZJqRagILnIGXApVbUgsL3@lR8ytdmBn6Qx00ocRFQnAFsZRBdm/ADO7AiDXiOBgxGA56hqeCugTmLUCFcAfwKUF@FXABd6xBugcNCXBWRiUxFRRxANKgEloWqKLAcVHEWqzifZZBPyMBmgQFfKaqsmGPFTQboKmUYoF6FzGD9q8DPVMiEisCgWlWoVxUyogLBqABUzeaZEMGrmkV/iJuFuIACNQdxcmCGelEL@IN4UPEqJKlCmppWmpEX5E3LQyHzWaI7rQCVtwl@gCwN8qoBtWiQW60I/hi3CIgrIlluBojQrWFfR1xADSAxA6kBQvKQJ4IN4cGsbWY5SVHoljEy2zx2iyi4gEReQFRC1AwWEb45xChkJwNgkMChCBrUdhbbgnAtQLPkXWiUZQXsB1kIsCOmM@yBgXpnpJcIWWgSONo8txt7hgUkCEyorYMZaR7YBbKeAI45kpFRQz9nOOfYExP/mEvGIx7TcrEbBobXMVyXYVjorb00cSNv3PKM12PsrGf56gJ7M4Azd3XTCjNA7U4fUUcC37gH6U3ns911nQE1zgFyG8txhkv4NvC2CwT0yLkwZlmfsT59OLSgQwB3AxAx1i3IzIVOAgXJG9FUeYYgEsZr900ASEkBYzZdo02494sOsbPAwuezWGZa7V4WoTyI9CtZNnSAK3sYxx5bVhn6S6PNsjWlY5wr6ML7nvk@B/MQ9EbQofogWjoIA9QbYy5CSPc0mfq5k6BmPWcwXzTOmw7CovdN7EOsC30KtdcFtmRM9AGILAzlAht6/gFQDK9BrAmP91wHrOPY8VEI5cKF/hkKHZYEQFqEk5E5MECgcyAK1niOMo2ckXLWmgIpE7ZyMslzPCc3ECULNxHFHXIRB95YoGfsjNuINUzbtImCoEfxULhxDb3D3YSRy05Pdfi50PUNfVFWRgMGPMasRSQt6DcNwL4vVLQJIso6hu2B3OTJzEQBEyi/53SB2KizB6EFos5gtwkJiILQaSK3ZYFQjgQ0OLOYydrDIQN3kHSAPPczReitnS9M9gY8rb7HrPbYdadsMoSaMAcQatR2ul2g3jfGsA8g2KDD2tM2NE@oZKQeoeMQJ2oP54s5s60bEMY2oNi7z77OegagHfr2LuSUSH5WgOGQikCo0G3e79s6YAqL0B5OCS0AJozRdRwZ3TuO4RGxgFwUNn1MzDN61DSgnXVnzGiAcgxQKcgWNtAucB6/eSF8TFBYWBhMyqeCjw0bmk4bqBIaPVQf1ukO64IWEenyUUzU221jOPLpxCF2ZtoR0ehwH0UjcpV8YLLXF9bvg1Q3TzUQNKSciBygnxGXRZWBJDYdea2vqoBkYBuhMMw4Z7Gmt5KHEOc3UhdfYZi5HLwSl@RhSE0C5URiEuMRshLkjma7j7xwhNyGZBVobe74dvHBLZq8O2BSN0wbc6MC2xFkJXTCfCyHIcHPug1IHloIqzbngEHnHO4ArXuDBZCdMJNWJ@oqK7oMTPEuoAPHdhZABWSGcDHIvA/VBRHjMXIN3QqJkZqLN1dHyLBnWjR2ZNCHDoeOCy2DM50psjReZRHqcrjGkwj7iiRo4PNdK3QZcezwRyOuvQ0t0KioiWFLBalUB04BTIzrEsDzHJ5iJMPU6gmWn78LYv2cmKAvtW0DBVvdnXIgUDzoniGhKTNdF9jgOXYSvA8KOhOZ6BT6BL3TQc6K6KB2fzNxGSl6d9wyJzcVljY6yl94wrnusi7qKi4IHdCIEvGuF09WyJ1iRrxExRmOFIrK3yIEpEAyVHmiC@oPdBL7wGiOp3Y7Ic41MTHNxPGoWxSTYMCIXEZjX9WHo5u5@wLckGgGZ9CuyVZhPei@JQneErpRTtBDkdFDd0HOgEYIsnqp1Gnp7Aq4h8ukyS7FRuGSvqqcC9My7E6Ylo8IzEu0vDJPwnPbZJAivRqWAINTyamTmEPge2KCIorgoCh@34oOJO1xP5JruOPYpoEGluCiSJJdhoI@dAAJyowJwofZNkdNX1y5dy8QXNaqVSA2kKaAbXaSURUhGJGRgVNDYJmkET8ReeQcj7BtJJJQXgx8zXMDYhNQarXGLkd9F1oc2a8FCARoFWyk5ACxfj0/Nc/GnZsVbaMjBhKx1YHQZLZHYkWAzp@3huoqrMbnsAoqRByxisSL8Qn0LeIlV6xQ0Q/mGh6Kv1U/K5EaTmAOfFpdiCIe1XebEfTutG35IgE3QWPn3KgF2T/zdf6QEaV9mSBotLdaKgeCzYHDYc92Th5V/bbIPZWWaZfnHCynrVvkvI7BxSDu44MHRztHX28ugGGZrfJNB8XMFQvY1Y4nUs8eKzlZK69HYcwAP2yuho0R58OIgu/NJGcSEZWmbehcJgE6D48@uYkSkIQQHZQCmPF3Q6ThYUDoElq617/RCbNeKgVJhlGCsEw6YAHM0IBZR389yM@z8Zs3WHk3MzX03TFn1ljnAAJH5cAO4snoeUMAC7xaXd4jUlyQQk0bR1JnpmjIID8fo9R8MzMkSkdI5uPD/b2jKoHt696ZYVkSBVG8EchSutuRgeatcccQFoUB9gemNkvJs4yjPE15XYjgdnsOwbO6ZUvgAwDUdWSHSdYgKJrXh7zv3iwbuUrtkALIThBuypVReaj9oRmN5AO7uDaqvIt6UfKYdVah08IeK/Sd77ba@byxmStFu632LM1OFOiAhGLTCeRGF7zOPAld5JkU6YvVfvaPH9/KuEdCJKgCUpAzz2IypeVZAmovksninrILGppjGfIL4ngiE5OKEg@GUOW2R8pnJPzexBwlMkn@VZMQFlLf2TnQHgaB/eE@GskgpQF1ceyZ3C5OWbQ9oBHbsZyewzYgDpcOgwRBbFpazJ2eY9@qIR0dsagxnAMB/osDN/oQ@hrzDSmOFCuqrvL5E932LoBLq4UsIokwRKAUCi9/oZ/rgK5ZuY8PPt@DTkTNZzKhOUMPoCASh9CFpnbElRyYBAnJfn4WFjCcD7nV2gMPKTIhgYX2GV0YcWfmvdCROKasLAy/MEtfdW5h/AtneoO0wIWTFhgiKDt4@uzxwdO9JzufnY60fH7OnsuUCoA4SK8FspDc53jD1rrBmyYWC8HFoG242LyAC4xBQQkG1seeC4xbxiAyz8ASquEzSYmvOn077iVvFuYCfaUv7DYnoSfY@HhQPyIo2h0LlRGXT8Bhf4700x@Nhl5ZUaCV98ctGZRW5Yu2Y@k9heJBx2BZioqqy8Ehjmt4i2JAZrypwWPwwS0QHaY0gqhbAweUF5rUQ9bAEhw8jVpZZq8PujDO/BluUg4pmEqjdEBDAF1ZCctGDJhsgFv/G9STyEn7K6pW5HStZrScIgbB5po/hF3rGqA6JaC3AlQkb1jZ6b3Te2wKXBoh3QQSY/KGP/mDfYHFQJCkUVPU8wPkELfA8VLkFYSj12MczQUupeQzuU21kFdALQM1DWRWCcfcpIE@avelkSMBPMnp0rhBhAq7Xlu3u/KGbwgyC3LfR1DUbP3l6andAAH99B7lDafU6tNGXW0kK@x2lA0/fLIC1DtXPKTdwAFol4xAmvRlS/hZR7/Nzjo6ta4OU0aDod/nSEP2ZAcEqTcO8OuOEW17GEGJeiobc2EVDPxWWTAgZGFUAV@IKQUaFPS0QHoK5ksCoRfFQ6Ac4FuRCGw2msHLwSeyI3wElW6ke9OJezTij3INjpZ6Q0AiDTa3kUt7OD44gt4xpHzk0lC5yKTZhRHHcXTd46OVEMmfvgzig64WQqBR@XBE2g6nbYEIKBap58A5gK5w2LQ/G2VEpR8oDRKkPOHgA0gQNs0e9IDPQGRekB1eEJ4SucwX6cx2LmyE1jJYUWqZIz7Y74xdnBY0O9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK/T/GHLaPNRVh6ZSgFKoM4GxsDBoQSQrogVGFQEnc89oi7o4Yg1NKuMhNMvAF9i93eBi7UNPl4kDVCJApLaY/GRq@xInyu69AaoeYVshYXfiU6FU6WfBAigkchwLpxGSfwRUJJOnAEFekHjLej5IBB3heF01IcSA4WJetUZGvZNnY9rhIlkhWZs43Fg@KaduIyvra3Fy/FaPA2mbTBtoWkbTSkwbZNJIhOGk9FEMdJkQt86xUC3Rvy6HkCeJBtIAxOUHN6Yw4ReL5ezjbReV/2vht8kVAVgHkJL@AE48WS1isZkUqxd4JwNyO@Rsu8i7Ry3XXPoo@CrIBBwu4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jgrrpaowMqi4ojQaKmAk3flrPnDZOL087qdPreBpjJyt6FfRDYF6jxEDuuc54CIJbPVeWgLcl69lyo9KqxjPxjUSiKFmQkJ5MflRMpnSO60TcAJpKnJ7GAaU@durtvkvwJmktmQwRBfnomqBlWFYiLl8WIf1WspFMxSFuMp4GtlyNxwEvbUSCR4XGEQFORPvmBFAJDRO6uOicAjFImpzC5vq5MexP3WiAcNQNpGwcQZ9N60NjIC4e5ZJvePyoQDen6QdyLw8Hwi0O3qG8NJxy7i7wnJ4qc0tMgn73XOoOnJGufCqD0iRHusv4WlyRJOgJyYdDomI/MT1swrptOGMvOtK4cAAUUwfXk/4YmGWw/iYNVGUOBaPdd1h8/T5AZ@F8D3YlOHUl8QmwAECnLcMPmShKJThZAtIFLUwxgS/iohU@KqNSJjjrCcbm84XhazlMrUJxWAYTMnu24xoSoARiCLSMhBYdCTXmr005oJGvW/MSvi91aah4mwZwxH3L0Qm3nF1H5oOGg0h80M8hypHRESzgH11gjzKvC9foKBsCzdI6bh96CCgNcmItrK2B76E43rAjjyYQVUhghxv15NodCJ0XrKNpWqGd75YDP6QKQHYfKgm1UhtU3MBLUsEz6VfyHh8WCnT0p4cP9/jYCXW22L3iOFpz4HTGIFf6etORYffSbA/oybSdgQloCOK/ObOOHGfEtXywLBuZ4UqzORhbOo353ByWWRmv7bQci4aCVkWdhR@7nm7pfBAq8N359AnI@s9PjqtyORJI0c8HK9PGccjFyXJ8HkTnHGm@NZge8jhhiut5EfutYFkbshnfo4AeY39RG9RR4L6J7kGTwjkU372I7gNc0Aaysj@KQNbQ0Q9YooC4yA3XBvmOl2rmGt2X6mBhOJXCccFxlttLVSP381G3O@ecJeczCVmTNXPOkTNf7DanI0azlOeBcOXbXJgooAKFCRfA3QznM69wrUHfsIIZxCMQTHCWDPp2C8Un0E1QEuer0AwQpIc4GUIcGqfYWBtkTe/WsAW0qaHEQwuxNWon0IcpKLkI6wrzh7gr1FJsx5@a9Dj3dEC1p9GTrRqfzEbVyeVam8IH39ebAGKrVgnWJC0LhinF42Ewgkp5gxhUTJq/v1XUcDWGR2PqAkWpCJ4CWsNEy0ink829huIRErpMPD2dfJTRPgPlA1ePrd9TekYFk1uKLbLzceh2H9gGS03mUQb1MLa7jtWR@KQX1D/j6hJWhL/mIFy/RgwfXEw3WLpm4moWf4khsMvIqrdbcG9UXe12gMg6uRAQtIZLdnWWPr9idejBzmVvaJmjBruWR06zj4UfjV375oo6LlK6rj71BH/JSpXtHH38aT3T4BCEgY4TWUVeW5NgQSbIwSD34LpXMOHCm5E5oo6dFhaYWF5VhkxNaM4Dsg8weAIVFibklwizfmVczcrSNUDxTBiYc286SDMjeS13LX00MmxOW3w2cTm6@bSPn0yVkt/25xDKLEMTLSBomugHWayw45OHe0dHMlCol4jv4YRMGZqd3u6DvLGs0AEmo4Uvs486cfYRxkmiFi5AkwJlounHB@KtAHGDOgGpIyvoGW4CHJM4l9IGZ5q@oohc4PIRhMun2iPCUQgsYSShTASsvDD/z22uOfn5LLM4SxEmAd2Je2XArZmUx7b5Wvag3yAxFILEue5Ji22r6wliX@tqkujHNQc4FwwqE0mBUIZ6na0Bd6PQIqu@ZS/rGanUSK2zRqPCZ/ghIsr0tHjXXwiq@/jk02HEIP08H/haWffGcuAgBRq5xVg8fyrQrODTLWTWHbemt1upuK6JyTCz0htw4J7izUwuWK7KsxiscSIWQkui5pc2zS@cihTrOSnZN5aZQ3GCDITlwWnIBC8lW6syNZkMcsYBvdBdVJ3L7JnjeWbLonWwXcvkS8LCzrrsI8aHFGAmmlwFGwbhDdsztDOsjNniZ76k2McE@VNHA5oUlowcEkl2icgkVGqIRXZ1hQ4iW9cYkYGIa485fq8DnRb442MHMvvYX0sdlTmIafjLU5B1nApioLzNz/@iD1cMlPMbMq90LkbjcZnTtM8cmkUKTc2MrOZRzgxjD86s2zG7pten11zQMA88rLYsd96g1aXXggA0meJP05MDDdP7EjZUp64c0YdG7BekPL80ZS7ZltEd2z2a00Qzk17fEVIqFSlwt9UylwUFJOBqs@C7IBjwSmx5mpyT1aD14AAPdIvAP7lONCv6zVVNbA7v0EmNIJb//a/f6AD@b9dOH/orHM8MDU2QFLCmpO7SyvKjooVeiyuWD7uPLVMnxJDpLpBt3YUi6VZoWAyapvYlCeSNAU5U@DUOtIkvkEVXkBnPOZ9nDL6LE1k0VWcD324vC3tjlRdPiiaVQF3sEBK4zGUaFImYLK8EY8IndiKKOzLcuzMVLMViRMy83vvj0Zi/QRy@sxLNIf5WtU0/ZCavt1QDFFK9ZRorqtzVz8YdRxqe9UKxuLAg7Kz0NLMsgVTiTzI30bi4@LyArtmD7j74Lgs261@VC/rcRRWePfaGUot0@w63UUMYrEjBtfh7WRDT3/MUGpZjzbTo9Z6U6EMHQvHXWCi4glWKIM28gWZLb01RFOp/OJWF6xWA41TbqVQmu2TCejhcHh/1U4pfKi2OPZHbHB@LRh4UvkpW4mNzVGB/3ewdtQrdlTnQLUnrRIxLmfmi5Q63goYzpRTHOMd5ovOFNTfDPnZI7bGluzPTChKf5SOYnFg2zu13G8/MtgPiwJCpm7KqBV1HpMMglhksuJslhIuU6RVZVGEuQmMHtFDsxKXQtJgFOO0RLkRdQlPvwdD4AlBcZhshEtlZhqm2c4G/peJDHzRh/l7co71ZmKv3YE6S1bZ06MeXdgdzQ444pHkHoV6YnkGvxYg9W5jRUdta6D7fBILBxOjg4F1k7ZmW47Fjeq9CUM8FLPD3YoKO4tLUbYmG2KPmFTwoWDkxq1Dd6jlWodhTdHgtrfWx20W@73/fl8OFHEpV7@BQgfjj2Kr/XcrXzxT37K4Koi1kLq6ajRhXdLGL2JQ/o7O8dKAY4HTg4pLtZ4oUU1b4AOKShHEi50KfBt@/Q9exDLVB1zGckjgN0h1GKBXBMHK5iP13SS23OrXO@zGlW2A37ypEpHLPLAM6K3rfqlKmZdQPjKFmMu/PorrW2BgbCxWNw9YXBu5GXqFkvH@mMn4x1v3xf5xywA0vYag3vmb4XrnGfhptK5mJDiq7cbcoM8/UhiB9D1F1fgaGZ2i4HaNnj4dztTqnndlHq1HWHwZN2unM5Q59PpQPFe@QlObkc8@g30qNiWt4uOysmstkMr4AE5nHmbOs0qSyYdwvTP6eS5hcZinPwuLcnRsxLk6D0BJd2LiUBWnLFHsKXCoptmkboym@35ObthzH@pCaAqbaMVEUA8mSFvCuqrFb4o6/NYXNhi48HPBodZcNWvDextctAT@oNK@q9OhE03vVpoRTqQOc5pq3rh6@iUxb3ZUK7grHMSG@pNdaLkv6oyGqXJQ3V7Y6LqE6LcPS@WdSyK2CV5KzK@HNMw1/ChinjPlE8WyCP3aDKQ2ngCyzA1pK3xgYZF0h5eudL8Ze8FkaaOLgb5n3xDDaymTPaC8LMDSBL9j4npuZjghLI8cG/WqEqwdRT7FwfarvuowDB3OJC5F8MNB7Bj/qYhWnnA1Y4BodrtbNjIuHLsp8XU4bos2Gl5eTBDSqM2PqBd@FAJ9M21Cv48Hdw203Gn8bx0Dfo7UvWxh7u4u1@07f7ht9vho9tC1rHECPI340yaqsQ657fVwgNxzOLZyP4tNyLOt98ImskTNKx@kuzNMebqnF/WAfBHeqt8DD/9w5eKePOO9Aw9JW0zfG0C95zsgZGhLZlgW1cKCHv5fx0GDq@@86grRSzweMBN@/K/w7dcue7oyGQ/o0h9bYoxdFlWgn9F1yU5cveKGllo7bk984g5bsO8r@ahiacV/MYlrmqN3Hreicso2e02r3zbsy3TL0kW2eKcGQD7e@l@6KmDGZ9BCdZcsE9LpTGemlGvU/xs/Bskr3R494txYaVsgri0boaLO3NNTP2h4fDUUTK@OAcKQ18i3hZdpUX349NkczoJEVUuHwLp@WQMOyvPtrMpZKVrTzYsaG/bUaS6mUhHQUyCUjAwKPuizZ@dVzkSaWzfLXsgxFS0k5iqx2@RB0@yuKaHTQjIzbgvscfc0thVrYydn9cc@7zTD5cH0HRDR8LR@2oBXSkSFr6LN02/8sQ7NmKbh1Er5NkLnGxso5lfzKSRUKp1qS7pjwacIHqm68dAzNMocefzOpu3Qqzl8hBbr4zflCjpvpYmXar5iO0eVTIGi6S0QcODRJCzKI1MYJfRxBR2bOBS/OuGynB0xdstgscBB2mdiycPHR4uoP@0zps6dGT8cV3I/NES4BXUAVRLKLFi3dCftrY90zvzaGki0jNjwHgk9DutEDA9C2AN4TvWe2H81VRJhJH8H@@lH@mSN/dLpdFxd908MFVKFhxcAUkhwnYqS6JugNC0LeHLcPj8CYNSC@uXJh6EVj685winvQpmRaNaxujmiU1f8uUx2XLS1bmYmL8WA49vzP4jzQEq3oKPTgjNy9CxOAS6@BtbK@bo0Wj1RHhlxBCvM7xZlxmTT@uWk5PfZ5McNAaAMhDIXzBYTzALrnZ7guyLUXUCKl/Z7TnjjQIbm8YK@hbo0sk0zbHK0ezRmNcI1Q8MXC8J4D9z0oj/Et3/9QCNLJYow8vlvWn214vqN/B8o7dsZu20BjeIpJVC3wUzV2gzXNuE/EwVNYLqJaWtuxoHmBwVrYZNqOPR5J7the2SsUVvYKZTYpFiJkwBJf23vyPBmlBloDfpcUaoDyN/as6cy0dMHADSIzbRDElvPR@dCBLvGQn750RAuQ74izg0dEtYldP3QW6TvPpq4xem@FCZj/ePDQaOO04Z1pP3WeOLYDvdEQGOXgyOAnCcwt9FgcEaM9xr3ygJ/OnckcE9glnRCXNvSh0YL6tWam9@mLOOCH@khf0hXR2CDpf6HpTloxrZbhfkGDfhHzMpV2PkOPjAnpFssJhrdBadRuc5EYx@Pm2sjcjI03dBybv4nbZuCjPlnNVaAroNf7T5TLuLx/blxgoX42X9TDc75KxOjwoy6WldU1Wo7F3yvWJNkmXxOgu6bhKY/x5ARyK@SYBNKXt5KHbK7kITPVCCTZc92jSfrFqsYMpDr5gCVAfd1tOzgT5htWrM6JHHdwB5sOdwzwhQMtQPwEOJbeHvvHN96VLWvQGtBrqcIQqc0jo4V7jVp0RshIn9yuTD4y5B@QEFnRFR4rELArbNQFlngG2kjy7m5rTo@ax6o5pBdx6qXT5bRYR7JNo/1Gx1Ezh/A1G5ue84cyK0/JuGSsOtKMaBRZ0Wn//MKWNL90DQQay5BGfRd0fmW0ang7OLxlwXzIeGDgJPP8LMxS0dXx@lRYZ/F8eshcXUPyTxAEXhKeJsjlQ2lnqeSJ4OH/8MFXFeiEm4VccKAJsK67Z/Ah82PX9j/vQ4HPHG/UNSeHkG/cdLCMnWCx8hAFPrxloGljWSGg9uyxxUcfepF1V4MOqWMSHYMrSRax65EhGfa5RMfLTW6XyOFbyZQdPE91ZHQk/3QFnGmQHge7ysJg/nfBBGqUN@JiT1XhiJ0Ucv7yz0XIvQg4A8hbzkgaevRVht6zg8eHJ/LQUxf2Tzt93IxxS46bO65BK2YiQ1Jf6G5kvpMvR@uY3kh5cKxKu48PZAywBN98RkOCD87MzX2Wjnv6p5fqir5UC0JfY7RYQHx08uRxarbxkyV2@64zMJJR793j4zRubPnq8ULvaOx9aB1dZ7I0@sGeqiYXkO9zm2YHl3HPBSktg3RigDYKxPiIn/Zyp3DVdoZG52Q6ND6FzhM5uPeeyReWFvKpfm72sBWy0lJEUUNlJbmQS0ZWZoOybbjhd1l9nplD5JZt@ij8s3Q5CkoOWcXNLpYeVs3435RiWMZfifBhkdTMbWodmRK0jF4fTYru/X0zpqrqMjwf612oV5ZfWlnzARbND1vO@XtMJRu@8iKFTtIIqEoy71xHvikNgHUr@MLhed8RjK2ly2BWAQidCwsb/IVhT3VbormsVeJFGWLjoraVQT433mNCKlzhc45nSi@c4wuX1LNEm4zJOxI@cSNRdncfHNwV4cjH5epQHz99zp7pHh5tsjpgNMfGe@R4Jhl9IeG4FZ6rt3Q6teMCKG0lvN5wcXsus2Pd7Tj2dHL3JBztbMWunY4sDmGhjQIZljkxF/VVbT6u9WzxMqO70uabOJzpnBwcPfLGB/Tu2/9CVTMZOtAIv2qGW@@omaCBswSa9Cmekhf1OjkIWUMb5RYZHJILtdHHxgSXo/DR4EVK/cL@rbCi79tMLu9OVvkVV/jlVqR3yw8dWVbOqCsA5lf4sbwcej92rIu@I@/qruEtWH@8MEOrClJaUZBShDu/KWZwEJQmFn3zchEfty74n4XUemKM3Nyw77TM3MIy7HTx6Er2BI9gv@3vL6fQXVre0nP8LR/cvji9i7GxMKEn@pvFHsRpzhZ6ARM0@mPaEnHbe36CtAUyr2H3TH5qI3vgjPbItjCTzxxcsb4wyYfm8OF4uDyjwBLxwoCbXHwu4AtQlZ0Ljz2gLXQ4HT0T0Rfo/bg2brH7LUe@Xe5obEcPcPbS/hEcfJcr33foycEp24mEnUolk/PXQUR3WfL9hXjMH98aCGGvrtiavwMQPMJNkf6@QzwNDDQSA3frCgQCt4Mm7GpVzZfYNl7KUAZ5I0kpohOduRSkVWfrl/52vnJZvcYtjWJZZP52y/AIVX4MKMDFAwyhTEw6U9n6CHzWg82AjE60Z1eMdBgQmtR8BmyyEt2dXfF3SUKW1i@fHTzbOz7ZOXl@XM80rsWkvxeY5822IbVgl/hH2Y4IZffRBryRHwpMu4ktSI5O20fdxwvKxaBkN4pWnSvarFDiNsZZv7RtRaFNsYp0DfmTRJ4a@YKgg04cdlBiqh9/T3OZ7yW1CKXiOgctUppQZ2WWWZTwUId2vm77/jcvCyFfls2iL0/YP8cVqLznOB0/Rc9gdz9Bivs7B4@fH@2xIIMzorkwO6N@tZTnx/yi/CAZUE9dk5bYVFncjxKHuqpW4/txQExcjrMybUWmI3aBziFYgB3cxOzH3mCJdYIPGIyHlaL8128o13EZV4smIWw8yFSc@ZjHAOwEtxf@6Y87/Aj64FCR4FYcd0CdJR3eIPhbh5dsHEaMUsMcLr8bh458pz3C4Vnzs/uGBLqKAKjygs4Du3FWVJKOb@EXHflHeQUJEYEEx1bjsCMey@V67NzEDcI8D108JWuelHGlAp0MJ7MdvPgHaJ7pdB8CZH1sj/hJNP65FTGgIzlkKGm2TpnltyeIkYDxrTUg5ZYB3Jh5NuhyxqjMvgA6w6G9Mt@lLkm1@K0oAWh@45PUHw2sSMBbx2p5yqmrvPuVf6b0KgzMIzB/xzdPMg/A9ku@rQvmX@bmlwrW@@1juGZ5iWYIj87zS8AzEuIfcR@578jmJwPMEIenhQVck5kDqKZzwjoG5ynwtwTMdgYnUf8UKg3IDWrMPxGAp2e4jQSe3VdWFCQplBBkWghtTPiqpBtn@BXyhZyqQCal8wAgHbrdw@2WHGAyWYZGIJybw@or6Hm2traYiGqCUS1UeM0q6/bLrPgqzOg6hBUu@pi5OoM4EGUWA/xqfjToWlJqEqMib4qrcWRLHQf6HPLHvgntto8IkSUAWRxHBp7iPMGLr0buNDiLsoWXSUUuZFj3AUkq9DhkSoqCv4n9qTMC8pnbvs83seOqPN6/4SFvHr/YjY6ARHqUb7es2d7L4OYHv63JyAM4qGzmZlcZrVvxBYI4RhBlcRH51l@y09Gp3VA4bTIg0x8uIGYbzL@o9JbQLC/3zu0DABM3j@9DZLH7x7aD@tA@FIYlNEXLKmohOStSLrewSH6J/GSgOHgsyRUkB2wKWEbbML9wht7O7t7BVw@fHd865I5Cxm8GA65e20qdSnK63ggN8Wix5qvkwb5y/OTBflARs0wXItwYJBm/JOqqksyGORDkbNn8zaItyuHN0i3P8Qu@sfZmfrPaqqxRpFv5UDMfkC4tXZX2aQPKzcS14iJs5fOrsjSDp0RA7/Ldg7eymkheXtcbW7VTOxa/TQkLGsLLmLyBjQBMp97GuoLEfrtwWLDwAsYTvPnJi7bF7OK2KK5n8awl3Lw8cs5mp0z5DhGPSHmDZIBFCrISBF3a@g65BD47C03jF0TyU5miZ9FEMlzIrMJ4BNRJcNckcpHZSY7@IYZ93etbZksIzgDihxkGZ66F5xjy83sSScG/D4AnnPBvn5yUJzKtU0kkkdsRrDRbdS5iAC8pQING2e3ZGJSdZ86Qnw9N85EPjcB05AD7BTWLFjYY7KvjAYTr0ufIoLFh4NwSRAZMxsOsclkKuIR/LOIkhQdPQnp1PBzRL7g86OQTk6TcNyYdswe8PZFMA0f7SFUbLDw6EQtNRyXacZHqbFYLK5vix7gnNIr2Dzo/czLLgF7XZVASjUkifhFPlhuQPrrHL16cx5PiIlqiczz9gy07Nw/0DLO/qa7mJPrIb53BaZmLuEWpdJtLgNtNwPwkquBymlJJ7nsCXTZWRbn8eOQ@BiOIEYnuQB@yxNjmp3XJjKyJ04SdpuONpBo/8M9mqRSpS/AhD5lRzC6ZeP@d0O0pSyhVIAJ09ewOft6YQ1ZXZbkBZkokydbx0qhdkLjw5JukABouRCkT2CqSECgRkCPeSGRO4BAH/QU8kMilM88WeNMdOjSE5iBOqNSsdo9FLgGblxzFUqnsV@g8VywxoL7b7FBWAOwtPhfI9YBd/2QNwBkot7IQmzHy2xwvRunGeEYe@UdyQHZikUM6g5M6GMCaHaHZ7rv4S@zZ0FbwcKHy85P9ZjGpiCw82qPnmh0c4uXnTIcKnH8zCDRTZS5ovML1tY8xGp7Z1uRnh@CRYvvUYMQbLDUWRcPNO3VntKmqK6nej@jXAoTMYQfgb4FqBuDwcMJgsn2B32Jm/7Of4a29YmJdVc@a7nkqns9U4KVW8izPPlo/laT1eqZ6f10HLWr0enIqMl3JbTw8N/rd1kFPORVFlmU5RdmI7288M7XCy9eT66xafH02VAt1@fWkIRar6bPGhD179tnb5tukODmfiqcJ0izZ7uGVqOZQcY2VS@xyu5CNnZXQI3je8I@27LmpsYtxkcVOT/E2XnFTVJR6vAH/5PUKHh6oXpNr8nbj7dtknen6aDJlpzG84ZId3id/UpRw1EnTksemaSrsdOh1OvBz@qzBr2mO8SeVSkjMd5Dq3K0ymHTJbbJj9HrjPX3K3c3YGD/7Iz/uk89fvHiBhhf0sDdHMR82xb5X9sOVm3o@xrSM9qc/WbtOXz5rbv3pNweKsYafQ/x85/oJmo/V/Edrax89eJDLpQE13Pzs82df39nZyT1M55/V89s5KbO29Sd/vLamaVuastbwPLURr5@dfSZqmZwo/@mP4s1nz77mebXs//GNtzUVX5vwOmebwCfgyTIVjPguwk9FGeuMvYHnrMvwn8xvOhGzjuZW9w2LvYkBlauxKf01Z5W8xtTa9uZ/@97h69goVtOUFy58R7HXsUIxxo1gAFs2sJ3HarEtDFa4jk2VarUKxs3/9u8hfu2rAAd9plvwquUDWIVprCZVKcpVrFYAg6ppkO7/9Y1vRIiHs4kqiXHBc5/V4RFzm5q43YBng54tAQ9UkzKKwkPZ93oO9GYGU4v31HtgH/VHhoMfk39sA0@2liqgdR/VU6lUQ25K8MgvSXdXVe0UGACbIy1qIYQl38pdWNTN9@CBOem8iBFNAVERXXGz70Ckxh1e3Az3YsFTefGP/RwJscLafeNhrQasMFvLbtRS9Kydlssc/QrbLIqOcx@YRJrFT8U4e8Ue@5VTEzNFTUyn0/ebaJ0gSqVJbIZAxnHEYnOYjbGZjUWdYiyIxmZhPjTcHj5/9r/@2ff/7Hv09336/Sc8e87umF1lA@KdQ9Op8Qe@Ys0VL0/JAgXOlIvlotK8Pk1sAKdqHDE18/FVPJ@NHzNqckAnp8lgtDMWPrUavujft5GJvjfcfJ9aaKEQsyirwwVIjUEX7K/Sk@rntYaEglNVqquFfEPi9BiUsVZi9ftQTaK2WRIbNS2vHULVqSKvuP66x5wYaJAFiLQNzxr80T88oXUNR5TXyG0t8KFQt5@1MN07H4BZVje0rJL/qLCnCbF6XWkYDRBkWS0Acn@tvFYsF8qa0lwBl1VuOxmG8cyLnatqu9VqvWm3dHhaeltXR/p9eVMuytrWWJ/oU33UGrcmrVF73FZVIfa2vsaOeDNosFTwnKbufJ7LctM3ksHBnyQ5k5gQ@0d4aqqmsg1gpBl4gfRARlDu8A/KwWKX8DTebtTfbgCF1FJb1DwbNcnPJXzk5v1GSrq@roO5UvH/t2qhsUIPN0HhGtep1NbLmiTVX9bqKQD50gcpc5hys9bYIo8wLT8x3zuec@IF5/5Wg0Gyqa36VtXZpR/EhEdqANytubzev5@SwXQfANTWQZBIplLrkrSGPLzu8yoI3KilgkJhHkC62doCArjeuq5d17eur7e24H@L3tf@F1yvt27902f2LAkz82@welYrQr5qtdO6UjtVTn3ia4BdVmroIiunYKjBF8JBZybEoHkaZSG2wTZieDZVNrYhxF69@/J/xt/puy9/D3t6Bn9CTNlABaHE9QR4MfbEZk/4Y9vwD7/Aii7o8KSGjjZ/2TiHoCivZFbmw7QJtVhIysgLm063iROLMnsFQRkyCCZqxYLYTKlTjcW2xMImsYifv/XE4/F/8korbca5Po2bM195nvckkjN4gTr2hH70B3EqWkaV1KsaPw2Zn0P/84uef/Lzyx4hdlUC5DFgfh7jSBFiUBMxSaoJsdrWANfw4bi2hCrEefUz6fmOhDqvPqJZizbX56oHe9VSqcaH5NefEelsPNyAtwr/e2tQGAF7GCF2ia/Wa/x7/Ab/2Ekb/45e4x87eYN/RyP8Y09a@HfyGv92Wvh3MsC/B6/x78kI/5738O/057JZtSKuXxIqUmpJvV6fiISSSmy7dvpzvK668Z9@95vfjFercSlOR@HnVFD/1WQFkOl58cr9uBCrsnV1Xc1YmXZGbaktMJgs47JMP9NXO9BdNVWWMVhmmpmyzMBRO2Ay4C8DJjPTZZkey9gZGwKCL5hGzcwITV349OCvC4Bc@DNxhUlLzbQZJGShJEl3aCF4MF01T4U6qMTiKwPEfFmVM3LBbODNA3Xx1atTZaOhlYpMRkKRm/VXp/EGnmurlXKsNTXWTl@xmAd6QiWmnJ4qfMQDykrouL5uNveePmw2FWSip0@cw9n/4eEgal35Pzh0nhw6Awf@Dw8Pn0ALrKXup4C/3L9fBX7jf7Zjtcr2aZm4VsC5YsrW9mktK6G5kAJmpKFb6gOfGUT41tZOhfhFAkW8C5TyKi8uKucVMl8EVjA0K7MAQTBu8L/wXACDDqS5C3jOL9BANjRevDgNTdygvLg4RXUH9NjwH@ToqPUf4N/8f9f/k@csyRL1RjJxeb2VoCeJf8nk5fXltf@uJRMJ35LYgj90ADtGubyuoZECXYKpnkg2ktfX3A3eieQWB1iDZLZqFHcWDnhILEySkuWvxD/sF5L2n9N4hemzlQinp5NMJllpBQdu48ybfkUTwskKXZ@03qqrjT/5ER2rvp2kQPlcpaJuMG7Rclqlkgtsm8VKpRhY1hOJ0u2nltlWCyC05XLJZKUClu0AbAasIdgigA0seYBqeHrb54KXB4d04DhwiXwMT/TnbCGRoWsJ8IabuFgW791L@Dfnbu8k793TSpmrq9BlOAQndc6p2eyYbrOJ7tmrK7Ep0sKAUh7smeLVlZoppdR40nETT/FqJEgqIansI61GqZaA@Wq5zST7B3kAWH5rq5Cr1Qo5MBeKOIl5@yFsMHE9HrsMOvDNJGeN8XVFrHB9FFq3hw@7vI5RtbNcPpkA5poEIfA6hn/cWS2VuHuS5QqJYqrk/1XXkqwGEgn/Q6U7m8ptbG7cB1kN/yYLH@TJlUujql5XL40yDl5eV9r@xZS4w9a4dy9bArQWM5VTodl8uHOy02xWRVHEXhVe6EjcXcD7sIZuvE5Vni816ljCxmk8Xq7cJ/JQi3kGdOCHk@LQTbBiiRAhmF3cPg@lF1R/SGNN0OiLL6HkD3SAYwy7df7rwMM6rMV6@LAeM02Tmcyih1mM@9O73Q4DOfzxfUMrxcUndDHCR4g9e7yzu3eS1rYkFtP2d3bT2vHzBzEVrfmZnbyzaD/a23l4@BwiPHu8t3O89/HBp3vPn4G7xy5mT8Dn/ffsGzUtsF@wF8IX7hvdMHRjbBjNi/H44jX7wjSbJtSfNYZCOD2XeUYT8j7UZ@WowK9tevoXX@jukB727offfvfD/@7db3/33W9/@91vf/@nX37/2/D7Mfy@y7/f/XelPL5/@uW/@J13v/Xb4Pif4PeH8PvJT7/89W/wH9n/CH7/JeL2R/4vEo7/BID1Sz/98ns/@umXv/wD@P0r//eD279f@cni3/e/tfyH8b73O6vDfPffw@93Oawg7Hd/i7vh91b43@LhfvkH737tP/D/P/H/0Pjb737tj/DlW/75D/7kv7z75n/UtOKf/Nt33/reu2998923vvPuW/9Ue/fr/1bNRF@/8@77v/@Xf/C7f/kH/yP9/5jev/s@/@9@8M///H/58//tz//A//0Efv8BTD/58/8IbeNvfv@H@P@93/@bP/wh/v9P//pvfv9X/@aX/g0ZfoMb/u9/9e/4@69@5T//9W9@5y9/8o2//tWf/PVv/P5f/u@//H/@@n/@q//@9/7qn30THX/jJ3/5h7/0F9/89l9861/@xTe/XPL@9sr3l@/h/uU/gsv75/N94LxPuT7U5cu/U37@PtiYpQJ0AtT9i@9@/ReAwH@NsXff/jEuR4ffkv8fayqF@TG3/X/AoN0uM/pkwAS/X3337e8iiv4HQBH8h/j6TmiZ8@GW78wsgNbfXBDpF3/65b/8EdliRrlG4@HYXRe1YmoDVJqNUsnvsv2hcojyC/PQQgB@St9BDjXn9x3kbe9@@I13P/qn7374G@9@@EvYYUq5UnonLamrxRroYaX8e4TDgIX3CYcBP8P0UzQoJKU@Axv7zPf87LPPhOaVgvse7l@B62fkxB/GvXBfhO8V@KE7bpRgVyxq9o0Z37juu4YpUy4w1RQJGhuBFJTPsknKz9AERy/xC@4QaLJBxgm@yRW9JwK@Zv8z40RgKQzDH7wmKjCSwY/nJ8GNQh6SSU0mAbpILGNcFNrgLjTzRunmSgxLMJmkJqDvggFSSIHXgxSrVqspjFjl@QErz1qtyCgrqVQVyo2xeZx0s4ggJg8ICsSspo5Yc6M64RFTCK8WoCMloNORqGpiqlh9CAlWJw8ZwkLgBPbVq2qtWJ3UENxbjo/UJPWA8oTAqqlJ7S3YqwQT4gmxh28hK8VqKlUrYoJYSF496SavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCLg9nb9xn7SFSLYpNLh4gwHhrfqVnobZqW3Ab/09SGXxz6D4z02yCEr1FSfiqM@2@TILrNZVMMAHAlSZZlBj@c6txm98F7wkGlKFn4pDiEFFEEUUDowHDYJyWkqH5TZIH0Y9WND34QGBZmfX1diNXErHgoE@oUhblnZX7NzxVXvcpMLJREdDZo4XyQF4hfofTX4zgFEWccMPsoxX/372@wj6CY9J25CUxKZZ2cE@NQtlIpUQP4NSclvAQNRAA6JUBXgjypkpKTEtJpxuRqDP3Y4eGhnwlyeFkVUkDmWlZFO86SjMfjGMSQ5bScTvtfmb7kIPsGmXz9r7yOyKWrRZmm5SqgKFUYOrGoVqOCAoyOb9@@hVqhFSvlA9BNmb94RcsVyRMc@LZvy5oGGyy0XEngejlTCznGEjQMCk@SJQWWYBtJga9z5pkInkRcKxbjFA6wLyc2grVMBZXIAYdAYzXMaPBwZbGYTwaeu4ds9/DJk72nJ8NGgwkGXZVqNIeu0zY8L4F@O08f8q0OWqmQjNXrCPqkrCGDEfbKGWJ/Bw@PDo7LjBfar4IEZaxCM1B@MUuqEBsOX2zF/LUcIt7L44jH@C7PypbQSlmIGqsJsbaBGgXQEv7DryI88XoPnAmo/GlRTKsFVOOSNPDLhK87Y4anxvEt5tCmcOW7vLVFGBBqlxKNz6MRaqsg1Gr@KiimCrXjvROIcHLIVC0jC7XP2ETGBKVroWZVLcPujfrruJxIPM2IkTKt1zNp/NOyWXiruUJazW821tasSwnTPKVqu8R1YddgvZSwGF@BhwlfEdhXwAkeSAMXezF/pd3BYcVf7oTnsyT4midRzUMzSwqnUNEcnDCMPpUhkDdo9ZGfEFv7/PMRq9VAl5YO9oUYsIs@C5b8SGZH7stUz52xa5Bvj7GO@amJNy7JHdMbWvoU2g6gI3Z9fd0FSAf7TKtpZOUxOvi@bpNLC8zXE12I2eVy9a2a2xRyWrn8NqtpAjgIsZcvdb1Wq2cal7lNLZfP5bVsoZDf1ABppVwhX8xm1Ewhk9c0tZTLlYqlzWuWgJrVdalWzWpZoewv5M5mMwIp@MKGIsRUUVQ2hGw2K@A4svD/P3c8NCeyNawBtreUIRh1MOa2FB2MLTDmt5QWGE0wlrYUE4zjWlbNbCnjmsCELX6CGsMN2lVxZEzwwEbuJtY8w@rKuJuiKlICmrjln0ha8@PVcFuKo3equIsXtxAkkpdCp9px2nSVnNCRW05nKnujqYVbDSzHrcZB8ooHHibezou7HKt11pCHzhB6SC2/maqrGeDT@FOLaS3dkduWobvb@XK@iJZwpmc7nylf0CY6@bMnjx@NRsMjg3YzbOdK5Y6Mx6TggQbbxXI@36jXRTFVp2QaeDMlZwLS2ho0HEPvSPDtOvbIk7RiAyJ3TLdajce3s6omqeVspihch8UXAHFYppqAMVNYljQi79JvZWXbsaFFl9N62rykcpe73e71xmVqZhH0S4nbACPXkp5uXYbWihQJV2bjtGTOPMFF70KHc@lPc5VFLV8UK/XKzL5ZECuNa@H@wOiYOu5hOM1c3o5VAM7HocYgoVMmXJddxxmVW0bXcY1ZwKxaCALyDN0OkBOvw@ROM5ji5e3kChgIcMgxB5TKz6ur0bq9OnCJxh6wgXpjKzjJDilU0yQtK2VVSc3i/x0GDf/fP7wG/xq@IVZWE05wN/dT4NnQz9jsMe4KHTnsxHHogsQHRntJiN2@TgsUd13H8/4eYR7o9hn3emjyI9RCr0c6Xo7iDcxRf0mI58MBbgQ33H80CHuDFmSQGjYFeAAv13KcRQE22fNnS0r5JDy0FJDBTy2F4EcHHz86iXxP9nZ2HwkF9uDw6cMbn7wfKM8e7@2fhNZN7htEzYcgvr73@PFNq//JHT4/6o4dF3/C/uHz3OwVOuH@NyEHz3yg0JmA@C@0klSDI9hrLL8ZGFQBV03fA83snm/MF2bGDBpf8M19pheu4uW7OMvCSbDjT2fIgFoGa/P9/qgq0lk8viCpbpYEYchs54JtZljHsSwdL5ztroFjX8fdSwZKUxbdi4xJXziu1bkwO8aa8AQ3SpVUvFUTMyE8AiCDcZsOvoCOGE926@BVsDhl0rLGBhvjdctLHOGDTmh0zV4fOpgLJwggtHSd0TqdD3sgvhF9RqsdRjwNcrvlY90OLsQEfaTHipV799RnrljKil4tUy73jNreBAiVPYeGo7vTdDEvym1xn8nNWM@se40h1FU2V1DXTjNn5ZwzrOl4CtnrcSpXB7lx1G1XoG/LlwG7teJ2bjeT/6vf/PHf/vGvQgctio90VixpwOVQ8jG7a6ogk1ytlYr5YimrFdPFUjGXVwv5fFrV0qCSbJZAKs2oRbVQzJfUdDFXygLNlcA3X9oUYnz1GwhQJEcpG2UAa7fxpsctEs3lPsjgfJqMvUnoSRbTQ/uYiQbEEQXUgka0G3TDrELnwtQMy24ygKizNovt7@9m9vdF8QFacHnAbkYUO2jJFzOZzQeiaJDPbhFFBtHhcYp4Zo444pZM5sGuKI45ADxuVhT7aNkr4DiOKJpo2d3Z38d0umjRMD4EO@M@3GIFlk0IZqMFZEkC8DqEBsF2eDo5yugeWjBJ9NnnPrvgJ4ofB9lBnyMejAN4FJR0Z0cUD7hlZwd9dqnYeZ7RT9CyQ48oumAB8hfFHhh6LjQ8UWyBERuBKLbB1J7q4Ia3auKJpPZIF8UpRw8iSBQnFFpvn4liM3DHZD71c5NH7JbJovJS3ydLCf9EUQsyjcGyoSUrirnQkoOyPXr0qd4Hiu3xZ@rybxtK@uhRVjcn47391scft3q9ljvd2fv4CL12dx9B/z4du61ey4/YasLjQKzdR5p@NpjefKDUB81mWbcWen3SbOZ0@4ZXc9o0MIcQ6zXkzH96mNCguQteu4@a9/VFU5YEsIntfwDfFj4PBvB9oLe4V/CQF30nrZZYQfJHWZiu3IaWSLdfpwd623UqaJ9U1xiLJ@Lpab2QaVTIgw1A6s1Urumu7QS@dRx3SF5O65NqplGdVDc1vtylmxBPJ1reFNNrg221lC@v6duqlktNyrjT3OnGWVxSt1lCvbfxhiWeJre1bK4snm5vS2JdbWxrarFc2Hy5MRbFZBnf29nNMgTMxEFpx1eyvtnY3sxHomxupnRFK29uJivXgI8RdOgtHA9oJhIXhn6WTGJ2UTuFIvCbvqdUTrPSTUzSkyrPF5smK5OqWuGH8LHMLVgdPPF13B45LofYA3CT7UyZ7hIX1VJRhPQVJZFMhiqeIsxW2L342snZyclnwAdBlfe15mf8gtqKb/340a4MirRvw5Na5X3UORxX3kV2NefDDxINnE5AMJcfQQ8Kaknghjt@XMeS9yZtY4iKS@ARnL8n@6emySeP5uAc90HX2Pe1Ha9CR@/YbYPhQbZmh@nVGpj0DktQrpievKC@u1mrVZvVAb8OvBbG@oTRKa8zMAcez3u4jZuiX@IuGN@jWc1cV1rVSWwCcJpVJqmvBk7nlZZqVzp4fu2D6gOMXGnCt1UxqgZeii7GxEp3264yNrY9vWs8M1w8oODgcB0kCdwak@gyI7nOTukK9V0U36@lmsvsWc6ejgcJ0NxbyXmniBVRk/haUORL2quFywCuK90qS7xMVl6D1V1niY78ILmdq3QSD1gzCS6ZV91XXaaxQq5CF0smEBI0IsINXU2erNY@AeGHAz4rlyEjfh2fAUxMCcCaHfLQk0PzutKuWiwhsQlLEnpylV61jrGv8LUliWJDkupXDaEmSS@EGrTTyjSmV71xiw49Z5mWqmUKlQm4qZu5Sh8qVn85qbjV4dg1KhZY/SEkviVNrwA6AWsA5s1V4t0vfCO5JeWr3K1CoK4skDeacrM6qdh4jBKQRDVbBY9UPZdJg1oLr800dPNaIa0W0tl0Li1toiv08el8GhxBtQF5ImElRMbEdGaSkdW0aqjpROaV2XmVTJ8lQFohlLFkeuTs4Y3s4AKVhFRJVvjqLJnSNiwGteAwfUsiMgVOUcGCAc77bGim@wjqyNAtipFMSiy7kbDWExhm/WQ83Ks3yuW9yfBr4JWQXm8XUpuZ1JtkspJYS1Y947VQqwg15CpU6uEa0Kw/usa88aAOdQwmdVMr1@stLOJmJp3NZKF0ZvOqtyXWxEY6s1ZQoYqukSXEVMY5BheRZkLOzG3YRJHbMqDq1JJWEWQaUMoWNamk5DfyGT6YxGMKQ5@tISZZ4lQMtl8m4vFNLR5Pxis49r0m@oOdwMuIj8WBqcbvqdsiyF9iWSxpGGDGEmmHXSYqgl0LOBzAciUhdilcX15vgT6r0BJBkB3ZGpkkuXZfiJUZUwR26p/noqwx9qErD1NbtZf8e4orpgGuQAceguxJK4IME5Uw9inuJt5mcciY7g7qmpZt1LVN6MmAOwZBNU2t4Hh/DNdkyzVAsXcJ@dtK1XAjzidsOtVTUjAAfY@xXmpdoELHbs7p7VR3ekc7wXqnnV0c0jwVRFGsxMXYZTwWv4Y/IXafdv9ofPcPi0X2//Ax7Z@L34/F43EcPAZEvY0Rk2C7l8GgUxnv30noZc4S6o3k26emdVnMSnxkAXjU9XVsXaGqCXZTfPJKA6qI2U7gANoQjuBAb5XP48BsTHk19D7XitknB4f2Q3ffYHxzRTHXFGsxllEl3KxQKfuuebG5dqYCUWTF7Fk6xu7HaIG1WCpqosYdKjF2JsXVMt@QMTwuvdx8WXz55Pnh88N9IXa6drXm4Bg8C9eHvbW/@jUIGM/m4oydVmOTaq7irw6r1SR1S8MjlDZZGfh9Vy1Imasap@saeRQ08Hn3Cz/ITbaKYNcyKtg1LZ/SajV1Q2PJ2PDdl7@H52Vc7n2685jFPX3K/vaPf6Rt/u0f/2tacRW/rng0YrwZg5BoVAubscvL4eXlNTzcLx9rxHimcptJMPOZBTVWU1Qta9t2hZUVXd/YTOW0@3ZF8cOqm2oy5kkxf45kMx/zrnwvLVMEr2ASg5zEAlZJbO/IzGvq/S2kFjXcK8bCvy3DK8WEWPHJqyvGwNKudXo9UyOTorDyW4ltvZW22FucN3grrbFX1RrOO6u4wywYVt/AnTQ4txSvpZSNOAP1h9Xq15VGitHAPKiKLw1jwz69Qeuna6xUuuG0YcOfseHRH0YKHDywBjZj4wtPTGwkFaXT8U9a2jJYvgaksKFAzk6T737h1zWt8Ld//CtXzavmZxpoh6VSQdViP1N/9jMIsOKUg0C1o/kHPI4ADaFKyJZc1A7qrRAb2ygD8/CBgogqIUoQZs8GxR5twjlKPVRLTX6MVidBwTZwE3SaZGg62CZZEYRQ1iQZ2e210wSDbeA9GtBshUvhK@gFXSurAksVvjIDBQ4D6EyddtOzxu6Q9jQkKJ7aSLN7EAVS@AqeULZGm7d9viwBK1M2bkflWfYIayQhsYHheXjeGXQpwlcgin/mIV4PruM5AxjStKEjkDEI5ZM8OnVIuwFpWzxCk1wTVHoeIM147ngkG@Ro4SsgGhAWTJAYmLkFASrAc74CCIAyJHzAZoNtsWySXZqpVGV2mNo1ruTGs@T0YI@zgNEQWgf31AeRKxgOnEB@x1u2kC78GgZhLeIYAOEw@GxwFTQAjE42FMHoEIL3BgWw6MCfBBWN3bs3y1W1anaSjEqE8M/MIQ5fUT3Yi/MKwALt6aNOWUwzPKauEriGZAcYT1F2geokfj5dJRKViWi9FgT4f2@iRYq8UVXkUcEC@PXFW0UbUAaREe28Dttsq8pUbTPJwsy3Ie9tyhQdjRaqhKeTj2Tts8DzGnL4s1hwhj0wopPokKBPtzc3uTPoEcd4gDgedcSZgb85nR9mhAztYBTEDmNBUUyLQndNF9QVmqYOTklLZNUkRpudKkf5oPXZWg5XNmv5JH4oFoZm8NXxPDA/nTU6x6TtQIV6Q8emA8TogBNcgg4UATzKP3uJZ3tsX@CFE37dUORojjw6dwkpH3NMB6LRTZ0UF@eJWy7otAFu0szoyaw96DCtxBJEaHRGlB2CS1IkynALZF/EccsyBpClY8Og/UVeWVF6IDmNW3RQ1hMT6Kq/b0KvYnuKfymqcmGemcoJHpgtOV3chsSPHYihsIXNj09J@4dSWY5zxizzzOAjvYm5Qxs8BtI/CLBpwOzsB4gt41oHLZtmGfBO81Dw24TPJjcW05G4a4lp8vY3q64lmlijV9TJmC5eeHqu2xH80nMl@AqvN/WCY1/o8BKwyyHLNfwDH6px3ModnmQi@AfYVOnsFBlnEIYJUD@Dg1/QKAxd45yh6ipgHwNMsx0coYCtGEr7FeoAqO1By8Lz4EZuGQ/@gJy4nUQbmp7P4G32EctqAgbkp/L4J@gADKz66jx08IOoWA5v1IGKkWnYHPkKtM5BB/xwy7lPfhg/oG4001l9M/Jmaz447HQorSrjzSKw5CMWbB1Iz1T0NfAsQA4X5GQtIaYAbEpMihx0GP9mdE7tAvGSMrsNKc0Qgo9qgEKiQnAjMovcDCGAxwPd48cH@6fFXVxcyHSE4dg1ZcPD2xI8vOZZGfZMEJcdZWQMhv69dCbeR@rDnZkkfkkKXv69PaFrt0v3pvwrCF2v6q8YScS7Xhw7x3O8DKA3oOOO8Jwhjwhq36SLRNoJfwELpz@tkb4M6K@M9CcV49cIhDEEM0lP0@00AEu32mfp7kWn4nucU4ME4FCLRuCIx4a6gWXgBSZz2A1DOCPko6FXyzqj2VCAJPIB2lnSvIRByGlg9e1DcwKRbOOC7biuPk2QfxJDIwEnpiT2sCl0@@QDRuhm2CU/w9Kc1KeNueiTMDp0aoE2xFw8y0i4XA2UH2iK/hPuPwH/CfefzBINkq1PGlwkQ6drLA5SPR6BF4REMNMgzDU//HPmQ5BBxmYqB4Ehp3Nu1/BrVyl2gG9ug3qsBoQBNDEEhBsJpf7ytH7asD3jYqORUnpA7CIhAmocQNcbhNOLTmhG7Fvn1tDx5pxsPPkQeiU/3@jU7vvUwGkFyxhWEBEGx5eJh9X1Bv4qAi4Q@AUGCCiHgSeKBjujhJmshAfokicQTl2c4ZhnrO5npkHSl@/lu4G4xFHPERsF1IgAQvewSJBN8GFBy@F34wTc4YXrQJggrETXeQzw0KR4Iw6YvNFUOK@pUCVFciVJQTYB7SiuVm8WJfCHqqjf8IoU89qv/2j21z44@11oF4tzTwTLO4yKEG0quDwORAi/uRBWWa0aqVfIgbKhW4YLPdcel0/93hqS2VACNYOng0XwLvDC30Sk8ttJXj@0BU@0xXJICtNqFYo4rfJmydtFgFKO8DCa50ebBoTgx@cMBGBkFkYz/GiTaLRJtcoZB5ssiXYRyeSEMjnhUXjoyZJMNvxooD2FN8Vj9TRAOsX1eyLAU3k3CmLQUGR46y9Oan@BB7qBVhWkOeM5RAU@DaGIjXTWbixMvR7JdIRp3QCAhHgLQIdfs1cWbjI8VQptIY/iqAx4FLf5ZMB5BRAYseAKP/Q0ERIZ6cAg8Isp6geg7YqpuiCqNMqLfxn@E9OBY/BTbztm5kOq846Z9I2/fxTHBmI20kAj0oeaySFDRk3mue2fFhiVOWJ4I23fAamudeGwxAJhG9yVsR9VaVlOSxnouDgFL9/yL6QeTpOB/oAzJOz@0BnpIyeXK3OlySSyW5Q@1xnMnu3gmf2Rg49B1us4hmfHR1Cpbadnm56RZngm3Znhqx2Gf4i7EJWTfaPjCYI/PMnVWATN6QpF3WYTrwNtNhO4tC5ZDtfx0ko7JM94XED9F0yR@MCefKCHw4TT@sJoj5J3w8Qzuv1oJ2b7LHE49D1xKHWHAQ9rg/wPvn2QYJjnzDRHOiEYRenWKEEH1/edgdMDqW/syQLGvgH@YAYbM6QPh5SXNNNRpS1HTmqnVpJop/WkH/WTD47KPtESejKMr80DmENGmrk3cYyYdRck11yaHI8WpHf84fk9jub3eHV@SQu/mWeumle554clnU3MIEDAWTayd2cDiw58q3MrO3NZCZ1RruIR3juLHVr81cGc7kDQHT@43AX6SIc2D2xhxj9dhv/VFRhE33vf6tPxjuTjKfCbAa5JTNA1K14w1ZmA4AfJpBBbkFxI2g/fMy0Iizdc7aMIAWIsMS4bDzeFhjkEtdsLj98PAN9B87je6hbd0yKsKvdckCf3PM3OtOVV9LDZMSx9anQSfsh0BG5Q4iNQ2IhfvV/BkdER03O4rpeAvisZ@kI3jkjngcpLSEZPnyeTy8mKBzFD6qGRcsrhwXL8of8t1oxDfFU@Wg16QDwew@HYcxOHP4fT4ZSfn23x23F8Psr7H16TeM7A3QgBPPDeU03Pkk2uYp9HibBI79EjhGHl@SLj8bYBRDxF53YdfhiK7i4pVG4kUjWoZWH@XojFNW6uqvEIVQQ0yaeQ3o8k7yK696a5CKlxYDMWtvthXcgtyLg6o91ORCFyl5U15ti3eAK60TidvaRXaS5gqGFM4nQjk9Rtki@SAmrGB/DFAadP4YsAe8aoyQkqKBuOafnXVjHyGejDiNTiu4CQDlAiWOQo97MRCSUEZgh@eR2m2V6aZvtWmu25NMMWMJ9kJJDQnkvSrwWsnlVVYBnd0RLujF6oO8NnFduGx3Z0F0crLuNmvGymWfw8XgaGHDfi5b0EMOV4J15@SAYvXj4mw1m8/AkYZm0rfhUvB80CA7hgJcN9dPdZONrb8fJuInktjPQzwwvSlePlsE4hzDa3EkYAFVhukBpxis12/GKOXAM6NhIq0wwpxkuj@kTjMGn6ZeCf3/RCt0SgJ45xblBglmLqXKcR6TF4OtBtBKeQL2jJZb833zvcp9VNYRBMJgU6XjQOgQcxPBafZ0Y8Y@hLMxrwhQwi3ywvzhGL9GTvmR0/daBQquT59Al7MskDnQT51yFwY5YIXe/jxw/qax4Er8D3yydGXpbPW9kJkqMc4ZxsckG2EKmv4isKhXU9nxe/9qM1RGPd84HwkvEgCK8lAhvh6SDD0eQcJjZ0hvNEQr64hN6MxqFBOd4okXpvRCOu4LfMJd7k7JcMGUO08SdXFScSD7M2x4LQs55p8FYW9gvEi9FrxusikipvfJCFCM@BFm60z@jqpIe@kcJxdpOmvmJZNxTE5UkS55pnkxBZxoObxvqIpx4qr3t4nNOHqa9BzAmOtSQQQCRmmArnr84HyO8Ol98DgTpAwo0EFgnWi7vS2@L1yl72Rs6tWbK3KxA90@xhcqFwFKYwQzloBxHJfBWt3RLxcckHF/J5oiH0G9J@gLZQJ7gDbzd1Cw4LpQT3fN7xTAPHM205om5LJNa5HAgtMqbkw@EFD3M6K9rqvPKCL6pi9KHxbd364Ap25ys4WnkIjwrg3kA5b@Xu2KZVLrO2DWybuyBLVcuMM3KaLg2reeYI7J6mbsNpW3A4bB49PHz6@OvQ6W5ubib9Pno6yx@2WhxrDftxDpmWSof9wQK1RUvjDSg42Y3D8V7fcUdrp7Z4i5dwZg3CgA6pBOTnt/Gkz8si/PxG24V4PGwEoz6ss1kz0Oe4Eoo6OnbZpo/XESDEGCU2dB9IIN4CvtOkrSXpro9mEy9xbzap@2o2cfFSs@n3Ylg1wYx48mexNWXsuXTtJb@o5kIQ6IQC9vCQvXi0c8JOHu2x/ee7n7CvHz5nL3aenuDm9GfPHzw@2GXw23t6vMeEuSWUeKkXKpSA14dG28B7GJmWyeQYQd51hlPOdxK7Se5@rA/YI6dt4DTVlqcP7ve5RbaNUY3H2gN1dIpjmCZd4jYwR7jegm4dAzUWhZsObfvDlf0MwrZApx2gzjtwOmbXhLAC6r5D0/CCnWLMMqEGgd8G237TXEjCC8Zo6RBdC4grsC4gug7hce4GwOh8/RWiGEPwG8k6MvMRFz4fjMGTvaMnxwzPOdg9fPrw4OTg8Okx2z88Auuzrx88/RjweXB8cnTw4Dl6UcAnhw8P9g92d8iBZyAjMzyA4IuxN1qZBRmDE1baZzjzLQ@h@kPb/Kg3SvDsQqcNkB6Lj23kPqZumW@MTrwijD0UX3DTJU0VsMT6ztHHn0Kfz4zXOMMZTAXT@gPxuUeX3q1n2BalBo2lBu2tIgQnCiYkNUnzEYMpw3svjAodTJAgc5oFwGkRT8c0mLiLa1Rw7JufX0BtOQANCa0BbAQVLFipMrqvJh5PbxHIGqTWthw8apKnxhcR@haM@v8U97RbbexI/qafQtgkdEP7iwRCMCYxYBLPEshgSG6OIU5jt03fa2xftwE7gXtm98e@wO7/fYR9lXmH@bVPMVsfklrdNoRM5pzJOcHdLalUKpVKUqmq9FqZmhQtopi0lUGg6L1Q7aE@qFDUH4Dv4cOKrHY05Azimf7AGcRz/oBL0SrajohVmeNqdHiF4lms8YdfLwd7dCwsXugP2x7tYtclTtxv1KWe0Pd9YTSHLt1KxFoeujnRC5tBQEVCyo839nS7PDB8visOZCIfJZJtG@RMgbBp41GDNHvjC1YxFbgB7YS89igUdsnJimM0DvJ7Ad8H1el6PTaBikx3iPfEOgbOKW3J5YO@R4n8QQZ9YkC8wy2Ohy63K1eF/mPLQcntqRo9aSNJdxkqE7TvIbA9hcA/AgYAZWI7nSbNVOSTimD6bcnKdtgHjkS97R9mfmDn1lXTjxWQVlv2r8HXr44kshvbJyk7RcIOuuirP4RlJR1ltvtDGOMkVunmGZSCzYv@YBRwH9rxFtCJE01zkBsnNqjtiyKurA3pkKyx1@8ZlZ4DF99T6zkw5WNqJY7ns3MtvqIrSYHzYRJmuztExzvvX/vG2ZmLh0g3PqpfYCFMZ@Wo/JyMCBNef1qR7PhD4E2G66Wt3e3TzB9fXLzOkMUC3yaqjA7xPzAm1gXDg875yGBxiOsuOdLUNVTh1TmWljZ4UlriKFfAYB94EcC@7nWjqNPY3Hj6O3rMJL/Tx9vbEpfKoGSSF8yGF3Yk3VxRV1W6VOZMSBMQQ3YCsiDrbfXFJZhaXr9GLxnshSJQpIdyBPftiUuepAhRrTu/aoNkkXdtyu7W8B2xRRYV0TXE6P1i9kfus71dWt5ycpFBiTDIaSsR7SrIBccxzFJovpoCt/swOJDfjwe3/iB2PD38ELTdB6H9EG6Z5fth8bRkwHo82D8eAMuT2z8EFtru3g@YJ8lpaJrTNXO6C2ltTftwjV@m@o7GHoDBuRc1KBqoUdtVj46oVWRnmws4JphoQVQ73q0cHYkU70@gLMg93DK0pBhE2PPifWRtG/RI2GX1oskMx8yLJ/UlZtGm/j00mGcS7x5RIdcgrqSHFhbRhdvtYMxST84stIQg63sSiIpycey@KRkU1iXgO9gDArJRpxkNtGY2M82TTxCaRuCSbi6vjU0bfrKw5rkbb7AcTkxApk2Q10HPktn995HXxxuqHl5gYWAfbHALVtIw38A@oQYVDyBjNhvvwQe6RXUpGtnzAjutaIeGX/n4CvvnGYoYiRfhvBY2xLpcHEvUeH28oJY5ZJCI04CHlp4ykS2aIUGJePqyaXaoE016dnwKgkUm3mn42uQKKH52J6cwooaeJ0t6QW6OtQXCpq6wPEPtrIRdvD/TE7SFXkuKh2RVIG0frCrzz6mKZ4lYTYrmMxujEgHy2urqs@/BTrZCFc/8LGyeQ5Lyc3Q5gP19BDKchKTeB86tHrgqPWKAB0jHpvVqwCQKwlJnxpwSaztNRiZ@gAvrhQAZjHOO10Qma3XEOIHbbOg8I5nQKctUG4whrBvKo2aK@ncPV4cC@bv1zf94fTzYMBOaDt6hVf67/jD0I688I1KL8QldW@Pf/OGwR9nYn@kSodjkxvSgsx1527HBK7cKE@m8zWxJW3onsdmtq3QNVAmpF7N4Myxq94pJ9V6mUDSbulfdr4glin/YjukiU8OUY8ie@aD3EAIkg0kvgdMH@fA9CTfgP@DgKpBAJvLms4k2zndxI4rAqrlO99xIs1ApWwvJ3m@HTa@HAT7c1JNQpNynUJC0sJXDPWeWZj1fjJUH5MJBz4ZSbiqTTVFR@IYKXYQUB8G9id@NCQs9NZSlJLrXdPpoH4UHW/6YtWdkOenlCuv5tZcWta7njtzL@sszd6lZSgmYfL3eZXg1vGn91ulfXLdFVwx@PR83J19/F2L1uXiGF4E@5SC0hbVSjuJ@voC/6@JlnjhXIviKAuqepoTI8h2CQiyKaB9enBd8gwZtmjfQQyLBpWLpUnEhutiNSpf1tbNSr5QvXtZ7Z0V08hstl0bLhWUbPzyFWRRkDJ/M10dnOKeaWle/dy3walm6AlC6hghyDYEv77xh0N8vH7yJaeNwAYAqMGnrTQp1vhV2Dq3Z0Pck2/NvbKkmcwVyrIULJGuOvIIK6PdO@mRUx7QCwAx6xYXVbDimvxPHmstnrwajPqWokIPIWuI2uLXmlBtTnjQKkKUeqMCE6F8AcKI8Nh4M8dcJW1FnCrxcK6DvpGOAqGNJEoep01QKfQoRUenLVT@zwqzvNS8QCbwG@ZaKic1NuhQZWC3MkhYPTTm8ITlM5M/wEQ9A4GdApw1YBa3cQ3L7sKD5@F7AB/5COqoR@cmQgbxFK0VMQfNv8Y38m6j8JhCACT/Ha66sVHHKlRcsJNl3kJQLGLgsvvHHYwZ0q@ROmcPGImyurxQBJ0txohFWK8kE3@dukJxMK/gnW5Ap0NtUM3R@h7MTSeicWr6FSEvqUkrawp9uVMw2imVUMZXZIMXcd6mBmi7YHr3zYVhNxI7f7QLSTIu5iBz4SP69sv5lXX9YxzrPNPKcnplKz8TSs5zOSEW5sjDBR5k2zEyp9Lco351IRdncqbpKghYvWejpZhaWJFHe4kN5w@yo3wiizFu6K5krdcJmLCFjpHye0fucMh8roxlcp9c5XfL3iux5jWUs7@t4/fhryQ7yyXhW2pokuDTbC7qvLHmDrkxBNksBNYXg4nTXnlCDqiR9MKU4gRUc6vlp2G6VIijLBSVxaMyktjZfp7JykfHKTqLBXoxTA2vGGDGoRHUuE@HG5LAI9VDyvAGCYCKjCTVyt1ThiSw8McBirnlVLXtBTg1waFpyiJfQL/IW/6jBHkdO5UvPTpxjzMfcePZujhOIhO58ajaZ4tIE3UX4o2zUA7NIVPckCXG2kDgwtMC6Tp99sNuoBp/XcsIUFEpSTNFdp0hKRxkKin3v60JMvLP@nluy3niwxh50/bEo4zbDIy8sK@bgPvLDUYiRniheTXg1GHTx1JEWfDfkQi1jhqys4nFLBNGY2bNWFS17OL@LT9IhHQplxSFCvkEDkSghvOp00JkMPWD7NyhaUeMSjLJWuTdhhQaMmWcr7Gbui6uQT01ht98xkeCe49GDlA4HXtPPWrBGC2H1Y3FT24G8o5L06eg3grHEYErbsKw/XwXN33be4Hnui0L@WcEg2bU8Ds5nnz2PHKyASCphBeMArhaeW5ZxNtzks@EMAnTFPk70H4A3/Wu/1/OtMswYlDGERWvoD6/9Vtayjnx9CIxwkZXxZBL9sPtXwyYrd2DR5QEzopdw6PJxGHAY/uL8zMfFTTorcy08tIpOm6Grr4MWElB5nLT7eDpMBxYYJoDpgYUu/REQZckRcZTo7FniQmuXS1REATUwzolxNqHJ0OuPgib0DGmyrC6A4mOQqLJeK4EJ1NfseugcnJ2FALrHRBRQCKijpIdwsOSh@Q/hIGTD1Bm7p3omB9KvT2MFhrs/DED6RgSmXqFiBu7QwcdvqzVRO9w7/lg@qgh4fn90@KG6W9kV25/ojBsPyimqrnh7uA/SRZ@m86n5IXxIlWtQMkUJVvngk6j88v6oUquJwyNRffd@vwrQAPxR@eC4Wqm5onqws3@yS6fvAEEcHB6L/eq76jFkOz50qVZVzIrKicM98a5ytPMWXsvb1f3q8Seqca96fICV4al@WbwvHx1Xd072y0fi/cnR@8NaRWDDrN1qbWe/XH1X2c1C/VCnqHyoHByL2tvy/n6ioYcfDypHgowEjFZuVwDL8jZsYbEmaudu9aiyc4wNip52gHiA4L4rau8rO1V8qPxSgeaUjz65Emit8ucTyASJYrf8rvwGGmfZ36EK9MvOyVEFQyEhJWon27Xj6vHJcUW8OTzcJVrXKkcfqjuVWlFY@4c1IthJreIKvIaPqgYYQC1Ih@ftk1qV6FY9OIY54@Q92js40MkfgTCAZRmK7hKB0QwCWwtEOjz6hFCRDtQBrvj4tgLfj5CmRK0yUgEtKnaOzWxQIRDx2GymOKi82a@@qRzsVDD5EMF8rNYqDnRYtYYZqmiQ8QlYByo9oVZjPwFe/AjMainOdak7RXVPlHc/VBFzmRs4oFaV3EJk23kraZ7FULuGEiXoo87AuzQVK@3pT9c@hpqc1sjM1tHoiEk7h7sVmJFl3KpUlHACs856IpSSmQYzjU6E11jImpZ/ftVpBL12H31MdTFWfFyGHRdvnHHwuo5T64ELl6R@hQqk043Gh3IDNrq1RsNxH1Myhsb3Skg1@EO5HNlGvE4Ad96o@NnYYLpvxgi19VQedJKhHh5AYE6m/lM2ffMufUfkci1fFkPnfQSsVEchH5tc4FEKiEZydsR7RqIqSTNB74FkBypoK/DZZgP1pGgZSZn6Ifzp3UYvPDkYH0A6s7orl8NNLKERfPVVNVwJhUSgPzIiQdCmKrOh7//WsfNmdbjnz3b6/ZbtOKoM5R3BPrBjO98pfu53EsUzyfKELB07yyj@odp30xJGnz9LkgnZL9khtczGP40R/TgKG475gFpTqoqU1VJpaT/l4miR5AoZ2gLdK6iTcc33rvxL9SPu5vIrz4uJ72/1dx5baC@IIWlhwqtTuTP6eXvGGWCAUSwOIEkgI2TkckYZZW@iM99AxgvMdBO00PIH5uoLn@Z1IAksZK@8rlknzsbDYGxiD3L4zVH53fbJ3h6ITsT2@frqi7WipcNu/eLy7yesh@LGUtSxAczjsE6jJGOU7MDCh0aKEa87Yn9i4FwOM2I0dtVp9BHjPGi7jbglEwoybG6Il@700EQv5SMdUoICcMxbil9njkzJAHasqQ625tIb0xLfg7US8YA0ZulOqNfG@Adh6@GvhrhukGQgyWIUSRc4F3YXJPdSe8pUlDY3FLgHs2RTio85jJumAam6yH4WvWvpTfK20YshmzLieKVup5KAxHwSC6HsKno8st9TnBGpAKboYfDlF8lv8PhJBrijcHdeOCqPakDGPV0S9dSRMlo2ui4hn@H9ORhUTdW0KVDL70ikaOxJdbIODGKMBkIFb0BBG9844KKOI5KskixgXy864htzKgbvQDhFybHyHTh3VnMklKKKHyLfVVQKwbB0kBOm2o2uw1JZPuk4FoqcMTL9FD0I/r@QJjPgb8KOE6BH1DKCAD6KkgSVaQXbVyJKcKMOGozTjYia5qdPEZg7s2MudMPk6c2Y/WuABLJ3JurDJwp72LZnEACZHBUb5vjVJmkXHmydXqccWRzPSXrNy4Et5FyhpoopuJm1M5eWXa46W8EXRzisazIq3Iei4jVv3M5p1MOWKbGVF0/CFINzVPyP3BIpQPSAJy69YKvVJGfl5ShTckCGWjImnJaOmATL0rt7T@2WhBEiMyb75cmXIhSA3kJ8pttJ14T0BZvnxiMu0kwsjikKHkYHx20yTj4yZN05GWJ2fYTzpEXKELxJZHSDE0SXoVOovgiasJ@QoQhWElkdRnEGUdw6WSAtTas3GnvSTCKHauxPehyW3metlsqR5QAfEkPTXT4r3nkTQLn7uGYzi@WWan0XbRexMlZLyPJ4a0qz3x/C0tHDdgOObjBxsuKjVDr4vfBqKOMXwnwWDKVGQi36oRpcNvHunaYZjghPqIXBCL0VWlniD2rSpY8WohyeZJxZEzYwr@LRLaV0DMbLBWFvRimbQBMKS0pE3BRr4vaWczFBZchQnygYhHpzQTabVA@eO@jhd9Mf/oZzPy6Bei2/pSOTGiBJF8idVO1RjMfmiJs@6Iek0YCuQA2IpkSBFWnaUBXm6BeSnaRdUyqKjomxS6klP16PZlJlLQUVRYwrawfmW8tAZyKVVmRoUB0stLCySqjM2nDd3bsZo2ih8WNrkTrtaZGywYuI0hO1dMQnlpv66RM@SSV/6UmIowe@4Bm3XIIiwrhmxXPVaTlH@KFNwcfAH7ZMnSisZFreANVvtPXp94gXlepQhv1reqPQn8AOoJkLxjmC0bD/1L/oNXb6Xa8T9AMP9mkY1H3MEg8fJ/SIHdYZ9m9CuhCIElpGptYkeub4MhyGDd/1uWTRCM0VjvyBbZopjIaT8gWHiSDNORoBRjdhEn8PkjHSdJnnq1EhK@5/SvZ4Bad4b9lnhVmF@UQfAUgBt5WwoGAf0hE5JhnOp8WpDOcPZTBwPBcZ4Tn3WOzFMH4JJKJjmBjGCpkpswSzEbgzuxfjemvstigG4RADLfm7Pl5sE9r02fXwcmGQIq/QUmBDFNbzRlE@RRljHEJ8mNxP7pUX/2LsAYGfQL/wbBa3zGIEEnFtFW0p5P2KjDIKuJB5YEAymiQxSLGgA7NQNwa0MU5CjSdP7qMGWf7AokiG2ZviShyRNmx88N46uwEipzFxcFJZFIsOxe3AJUh5ZOfvZ1j/e/azNPjxEJc1ZyiYdiRk20D6PlI1gUp4fWvCvNZEmWMqf3/ErKw8ttcSBCzNMjkzrhG2U2rlQh4oAc@veKzVH4IwTiWoJ009FsNRf7D4SOrdKztmRmabReum43zXEJiZrQST5VKLSFua4OOkaCXxSTBNnGJkaQY8hNtXetZsniTiuNTA8VZqTL5Dh/toFtlN6UlF93eLxz5Oitdo0asmGj2kCHcMUlrU3@sNaHjjfgkiYfL2qkESo4EiozHhRwNUgkyaSo@nEHGfxD1BjxZQDuttAe3M/rmXqEkjORXyVCXFglwiPTFwOzptglwatNH4AsPE8QpXCym94By7EzrKK2TOMcgwJjBAXBX7mUgPxRrcqLMSfES3A7TtBloLFVASwdOWaeGgg/5rglFUfqnckRYPjUmmcFZkSGMNCXYVlOshSMrfHF7rjTFBmSIFDPEZpNAtmpJNF49v1c@2BfIBBC5NydLSN@9iYxyxDNjAHzOpMcY1cFSVLBkbUfGB0CDRAGMBdimdrs/bVVz9BUPmeLRukMMINhD82cafZVkCw3mv5TW1sci4NcEsjiQ3jzZHZLa4SMRQ/I7kl0ORl7q0cQUAPmMM5UsFgIBhTQl7PBSg0Dsm58UQlX0EBUsFHJbwkaKiRnaeM9KRqDLD81UjR35WjpcmjMxMILCwmJ0nQgTWLLOzRFBgopuJi5Hjxez2RDlgQax4nykOXSF7JU5D3XNMQLpROe9EEqVeEG5ecjAlPl91Yomavyn1Zd5IzSdTgT4aw3qmkExdz8dSY9WurMSLxkoCPRyz1lgikMIxEdZS4ef@kWuKGfJc24Qam4zYKkPaZ@ON17DLhH1b9tdQbJJTtlpjKHimZ7jafjX4ipVYUPaHA7CLRToywNjtP91aZZmqMJF3BVBcOuXsYvOGkFasKZzqsVm401WR9nSAArWn7bfFh@O9vVjY1/OJMjS69Ier@XwemfjcDH6vbKtRlRT0c/HcufZVt5sb3Pxp@OE8R7Lf9@lKgA21g/ahS2BQhNn@sMM3QyAOkBVzZ6QjK@71r9pt8woGPKHEzoNu45wyGoKgCSjQRi8fjkkBRCDlBPsFG4jt@yL06LvxeKEpoahjKCiNJsHXKXV6BuTBD220z9YnVQQMBbOyZoJ5yyltfcMZBG82oc6i8MXOt8g8OfXW73b7rviIVwpjpIC5u2SBvT2zQJ6z4AkjefdehRSP1hX@ddA1/Ioxi8nrCE5NTOqeCRUXHmPjH/mdynhgp@qfUzCtQJOXsZnLGJ/aFalOypHB4h8BlvkQ0H5U7ktvYDeJTsnMMNXLERw9AUbPCu7MvU8si0M6MUmz7@dGos5GN0vBGqDpDq0FVCx76l5qyT3ZNXFTp@NCG2mYZxgSJ4y58rgS6Gr2rxOL16N2@3FSka4B4I79IYnIN6H8nECkMwAagXL4AT0xiva/ZWBY7yUCivACBy/rmJY7WKCBBSzrSbP0@41dLpfFwmB5WZTL2/CQyYjydlns4oftbbEL79v4/rS0srpaZJm763yDj9vq453YBhik4VxuXgx34RXSSug3htba2MULudKCW1xolDa3imGuXt5Gt354@tu//@ff/uO/cmX58j/4sk0v9c86UzabzS00vy08vSvie333bHHhvL4wOFvsFJHL/k5Rw/vVUcaLzEezw3MrzbOA8ZXsSNU@m6LPyKJCXfh36Q1/A@myIdLNMJeWX0O@OYpkbLrpG9999KM8hy28unQguZUHJNIAdILqeOidpo8GeDDfACUBF7QD5fJ8tqIU9xgORmfQpyppGYmH1qzXPvq0RJEU0BcXZqxM0Av9HmrAr2nNy82zLA9@g1FD8m/u87uws90fi6VTWyzlxZIrllIp@imsvYSvzkIuQO9czgbbgVTKhZToaAHNDEUY0EKP9g90106C3Ja1QFf2ICQVpoIysxecq3d/5CzDF66FHWsOL9YUrCKhQyYskv620LuDbvkGOe5SMVcbWig05C6GKjNOVHT/4hLIC9kQIKr5kgmy0Ycq8aSPPJLxKae@yL626DYhAoxkPXqzR@MeP8BctNCTNs@xvRRec0Tm8/wV58YiO0MT2pjC9UcI0IEKbyfz5Em4mF602MrbaCU1k72wzfZJ5mNbh4k/UrbpXOgPYTABW3ObhFvoSb8WacjNxysiFejjFaOqVNL2W1hGkcur7igYSHcFqh0H1Ddd2x2PJOxRAsRwOGb/xvQII0WBihSV6Ba@LGsiWn1sOo@EnnRNhw52snxyZBAh99mGsX2bGNtOjrxEFDswDxBS2pSv7QXdUEZdGRKxO97wHG8H9Np0odqIz81In4dXqSYw7rc10lmCTCbn0XiGpqQHQ69z6bkifdA/HnqTKkxbsPIZNbMOtBBDMCESOPhk1bOapxDmFskuIYroppDlEF5e0J3I69G4b1Pa5wS7VA0FGXYFB0GMnYiS/m2srxJ0jLj6BzrBRHlKeOvTSCliSfKipZGElDLdZmiYTQ0dS9Vgjh09cFIWo6pHpuIFWegKJ9pLOvgFSd7FGAGy7pT0ApSuCGsvsX6cnTp@z4tNToOupRz9c0XB8yKOZ7qKkq2RLHUJaiG68Q6xgnXk53gUCJ6bVDgja862505DeZ1b2pxHKMi3tsXPeSLQF9DRBWbkGSJOegELy8QMFd2BkRVVsvwHCO2u1wH8JjfeBFnxNG2/ms859c@nvbMl@7R3e/rVIUykSFazbEak5WG2klhyrMDMmHNjr8oqLVShBk978QynPcE@LAYJAJGcXf@cO7vNAUKnabxh/jTNBIl1GWKSe7i@HILPTaGZjmORS1tzzpKjOt9@VXAEzK30i33IHxz@BSzUppLU9LDPGbYBFPnp/n7FLidhbn0l/3yl8Bx2Qh1/nBn6VzjfZsKrc38MS4kQt7Mw9Zx@jXFDjBB349ArwscxtJOvNWHfk1A6KUkRKoc51WNptoIyWeYJyA9UpnCp6OLi6DweHj7iht8VwHIqL8WCYtNBg/tsnD/D/iXW44Uo15LeIcyRaGXANiKkQs0gZHX5yn0c6qjhskh@Tlmxg7FbCQh0by5tzBa9fi8jF2tOdrGIi2j0mumu59fzyTE6NURjI3RBLqYW50Vh69WLv/734e/pUXprJfdxCL@j9O/ptfU0P8IDvD1Tb9fprfQmZlu7S09ysAeGxxd//V8ov/UngIMpk034s7WqYK1N0luZEhW5TW@twUNhZQXq/b@//AXasMA7NryLdaHhCkKsqCiy4/WIdyFdVLGVvC1djMQKOWYhDLYwhL05vKBh1HhlPU9qurS0qrj2ZeQrZY8ip3gyzBqRqRBrMpQ9BayMuEAJK8gwSGVC0RaG7YYy20DmjdAUX55k10LYAXyR5hy6Sm268SREk6EF3hZBB9pcI@zn@WEr/yqlzTs2UsqmpKiWkLi1k7J2/Vnx/wE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/u76k3)

bc has `#` line comments, `/**/` block comments, multiline `""` strings without escapes, no `''` strings, `quit`/`halt` to exit.

To hide Joy's `quit` from bc I use ``` ``\/* ```. This doesn't break Joy somehow.
`` ` `` fixes Retina1, doubled for Pip, `\` fixes Thutu.

Main code:

```
*/
#1""/*
333
quit
```

Answer (score 4):

## 371. Befunge-98 ([Fungi](https://github.com/thomaseding/fungi)), 16278 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."4F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<          @,,,"369";@,,,"364";k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@  @,,,"368_"z;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk5mnjx58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@9w03N71FBr77OTRo@u@WfY1ybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrZwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//0YZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@x1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79nPs4EBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmOfgKpwvXSoPiDRjE6hX9NblQ1g@JYkuEvoRyXBAEXGAN0FOQM6IWiZ5XKvo7NL4B4uk2Z7XBUJVBJVzoV5GXYvzMtHBJYlWl@ZZ@G5XXJIkVENa4DRqeY0SCwh8D0xQQlF8FAUf2xFD5L2eBjJNdxzatM8HEtwUSTJLkLhFwaABBXGBOHD7JqTti@u3LsXCC4btRoQG0hTwDZ7yahGG0xYysCpIbJM0oifiTxxjifYNxJJqC9GvuKlAbEJKLVWZxeToQs9jt6vBIgEaBVspOQAsX47f2qeTnvXG9pGT4wkYq8DocnsTsSqAIM/7w2127AaX8IqaL1xxCoSL6Yn0DeIl3yxQUU/mmt4KP7W/KJEWjiBJfBpdSWKeFLfb0HQe/Ou5YsE3AWdnXOjDhT/1J/IChlR2pcJgk57o6dyINgdOBz2bPfkcc3vizxQ6Zh2ZcnDcrq6Rd6bGF0M0j45eHC0e/Tz7RUwLLNTue6hmLlSAYfa6Uwa2FMlJ2uVzSiMBeCH7dthY8LlOKLgBzPJmUVEpXkXBpdZgM7Do69dRwlIQogOygHc@Lsm0vA4IHQJHd0bXhuE2SCVgizDJEFcJh2wAGbowKJjuB6U59n0zRtsvOuFGvv@WDJrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8JoAFQZ0@HxEpLUihpo0LDQtXNGZQno9Rar5eGBKlIyTz8eGj/aMagfXn1SSKongTkKV0tycDzVtTUMFXxQH2B64uS8mLgqM8TWVdieBudwnBi7Zla@ADANR1ZIdJ1iiomjeEsu9drxv5St2QAuidIFyXK6PyUPdDCxopBw5xXVR5V42iFLAYrEKvlSNWGLo8bHXzeaOYK0eHre4iz14UKC0KwDgQyI0uBJ16EvrICynSF6v94h8/uVFwj4RIUAWkoGSexWTKy7ME1F4kk8U9ZQ80NMcy5M@J44lMTCpKPFgXkLseKZ@R@Pszc5LIJPlTTUJcyH1390B7GET2p6xpJoOUBtTFcWRy@7i@1/WARmzHcgYO24I0XDoMMgSxaW01dweOfaOFdPTEqsZwiRD4L07c6GMYa8w3pDhSqqi6yhcbdds7By6tFrKIJMIQgVIovvxKP9MBXYt6Hx98Yx8GETWfyYTuDF2AgkgaQhe6uhFf8mASZCT75VlZwXC58EZvDwKkyHodVtpndGHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv7KIn3i3MD4K2d@jbTAh5MWOCIoO/j02ZODT/ef7n7RnGj5/NJ7LlMuAOIgvw7IQvKQ4w176xbvmlgtBBeDvuFi9wIuMAUFJVgtmnouMG4Zo8i8AGuohi@0Jj5xhnbcS16vzDmGSq/sLiehp9j5eFQ/ISjaPQuVEZevVuN4jvQznEzGXkVRoJcPpx0ZlFblVdex9IFC6WBgsCxFRdXl4BDnNbxVKaAw3tzgKfjkFogOc5pB1K2RA8oLrXkja2AJDp5mrSxzMARdGBfGDTcphxRMtVF6oCGArqyEdSMGTG@AW/8ZtJPISfurqlbidK1mtJwiBtGWuj/E3egboDolYLQCVCSvvbLmveY9NgcujZCuA4kxeYsmOTyGY4HFQJCkWVPU8wPkELfA@VLkFYSj11OczQUupeQzuaJayCugloGaBjKrhHNu0kifdIfSxJEAnuT0ad4gQoV9r6vbfXnLdwSFBbnvI6hqtvGi2bRbIKA371HZcN25MW811Fayym4m2fLjJ6tAvUvVQ9oNPIB2yQmkSU@2hp/19JvsrKdT7@oxZTIa@2OONGZPd0GQeuMAv@4Z0b6HCZRooLK1FFfByG@VFRNCFiYV8IaYUqBDwUgLpKdguSQQelE8BMoBvhVJwBazGbwefH9HhI@g0o10bzpxj9ZIUK7B2VJvDEikyeYucmkP5wcnMDqGlI9cGhoXmTQ7N@I4j657fLYSEvlr/EF60NVCCDQrH85I2@GuBiACSkXqOXAOoCucNh0uZhlR6QdKgwypTDj5ABKETasHA@AzkJhXZJdXhOdEPstVOrWdcxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17rNXrRuED2r8TgAjSoX4eu0KN4xunyWlSemWoASqLORMXJwKgGkK2IFBlVB5wvqqAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfY/T3gYl2DzxdJI1SigKT2WXziKrvSNxRdegPUfItshZWPNLHf6CcBApa3N9AsiT8DStKJM6JIn9N8CwY@CMRdAVcMocZAYaJec8aGfV3n4xphIlmlbQjxOF8EuohvbGzEK/F6PA2uHXBto2sHXSlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/VvyqEUCeJVtIAzOUHN6Y44TeqFSyrbTeUP2nhs8kNAVgHmJL@AA48WSths5kUqyf45oNyO@Ruu8h7Rx3XXPso@ATEAj4u4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jirrp7RgZ1VxQGg0UMRNuvNnINFvNi2Yv1byKpzF1sqrXQD8E5jVJjOSB60zHILg1chUJeFuyka20qp1aPBPfSiRKkgUZ6cnkR6VkSue4TsQNoKlEsxkHlPrYaXSHLsGbpbVkMkQUlKNvgpZhWYm4fFGC/DvJVjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7zQgqNHlcYZAU5Ej8wZoBI6Jgxx0TUFYpC0OIXd9RvGeDh3oxHCWTeQsnEGfbFXBbf0IBePcsk3PH1UoFvS9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs85dxd4SZvK0s6oYNw9k/ojZ6Irn8mgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNpPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3ZDgFZhlsT0sDVZljwegOHRbfvA/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDryvBDJopSCS6WgHRBG4pM4Iu0FYtmZVQqBGc9wdx8vjB@LYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMClEAKgXZP0Z48oR6sSx/QzNeNdQk/lIY0VLxNAzjiI8vRCbecXUfWg8ajSHrQzyHJkdETLOAffWCPMm8L1@gpWwKt0jruEEYIqA1yYi1srZEfoDjeuCdPZpBUSOCAGw3k2h0Ineesp2laoZvvV4IwpApA9hAaCbVSG1TcIEhSITDpN/I@nxYKdPRPDx/u87kTGmxxeMV5tPbI6U1BrvT1piPDHqTZPtCTaTsjE9AQpH9zah05zoRr@fCybmaGK83maGrpNOdzfVrm1nRdp@NYNBV0W9JF/Knr6ZbOJ6GC0N3PnoKs//zkuCZXIpEU/Wx0a944D7k6W47Pg@iaI623BstDHidMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDYK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjguSnuhauR/Nun3l7yz5H0qIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xGiR8jwSbgxdihMFVKA44f7QtfGKFI/vbpHDlcWn4SaEoWEFS4tHILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHejfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVygYpqJq0sH@jquE2DY8m2wVKUhU8BdSJmZaRmrPifusyrniEhj4Tm83ZRxntC9BLcLfk5j1lYFRpj9MafFWDkLgvw3bmTAKJD2PxievuEPgMS82WUQntM7X7jtWT@CoZEAzj@hU2kL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2fN@Bea9L6zQiR3aIhIOg@F@zyNH12yRow5J3J3tgyJy12JU@c9tDfKWVf31fKZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdo48/a2RaHIIw0nHlq8RbcRZsTwbBGQQl3EcOLtypMzEnJAnQTgQT66vKUKgZLZJA8QEGz6DKwoz8GmHRL43LRV36BmiqCQNL7s1HaWYkr@S@pU8mhs1pji8/rkc3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8OgiFV2fPJw/@hIBsr1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNZVOsBktPIV9lEvzj7CNElU2wXoaqB9tP30QNRVIHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6CcL9Vd0I4CoEljCTUiYBVVpb/uc1VLb@cFaD4FGES0J24VwHcmkl5apuvZQ8GGpJbIUqcK6swXtQ2E8TFNtWkv6FuhEvHoGGR0Ag1aDSY9Aa4HEQWWatV5XsAIC4qYO4AsSuK1BS0i72mBk1fA28QaQiCn7z2lr1oZKRyK7W5ChRtLvM3oPP6R@AihGXQnrEy280E9fcbHZmXga8Fcs79nNTpa6cvKmyTO0Q@50zRgw1TxHRof9XyPqnlXVjQyZCV0FQMViRgCTH/eIBPsxROnB90HkxGHokkuwiRriHK2eUl4ZBtaoxwCC6V8ca4CrRPYExPHKjNE/9oQFQ6oN7qbyTBPtsUxEDNWl6pxRAuwitn16RT6UyMpuPSoWmfOrTeE7raGVnNo0QYph6dWjdT4iZUui1FDcvA42rrSueNOn26rYhAyx7@gjp50IS6LwuDEKkrR/SgufUVOS9vIlnK1t@eSiMtuJn0@o6YUrlEkfudjrkuKiAB94UFzxXRgEkhPWtyTlaDswY4FQPjETAurr0sqn59/xFbwru/j9Z//udv9gD/N1tnCAMFzjyGjjYM3dhSUn9tY/lJ8YVuqxuWT5BPLVMnxJDrLpBd3YUq6VboWA2aFuElCYb/ES4p@C0OtIk3kBpvITNecr4iGDxXZ7JqUc0GltldF/fafiyeFS3/gGLXIyRwIcg0KBGxLt4IxowvwURUbGRjdxcq2DTFiJh5uw@nkym/g@B6ZyOaY/zd1jf9mJm83lENhe9cv6XJXf102nOk8ekglFMLK@Iuak9rwBKIA/5ycBudq6vPK8h3ggfPddEWQ5tyTo@7qMKzp95Y6pAW3uNv1BFGt@TgWvy@LorpH94LHeuxZlp0e09K9KEDofi7IRTcaypFkGZeQ7Old@Yogww/nMrCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0qrC/w/WOVoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatRI4DUndq6e7CdQuJL8oRLCOsm5H2h41nZtcBcWDM1KKsasHQERkwiGUGW@MWGeF2YrpFtj@Yq9AYHCeRQtdqFuB0J7hldA1NvQdD41s1cUNshEhkZx2mus45/taKD0NQTfl99Yj2ZmWp3oM5SVbX0mEcXzscLE0O4uTjHYR6bnoG3VYj9nRlQSdda6X/chcIpv2i03h3kbVnWo7Hjul@G4IGLmCB31cTdBSXpm5LNBkedd/Cg4I9DosG1a2BYxVKA0WH29pWn7p95Pv@8305XMihVPUODhWIP46t@s@1fP1UcU/vaiA6sOji/taI85YhdhWb8tde1tcOFANcuFtds0eZEqWUFT7VtyZjXHI51@fB82cYOtahNhg6xnMSp0G6wwTlEjgmLhexf5bccrfn1ns/pnQDbPGuSkQa99QyYLCi@40mZVpG/cAUaibz/iyqb02NqbFS0TjsvDLwWP0tSsb7FyrjV2PTn6nHxQE8mhLGeuNrhu9Vahyn8e1WZqJbZte4W5RZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdNxMMbCn46VWXdLO7KPbUTYcB13a6S2VDkM@lA@V7pCUluRzz6DfrRoT1/Bwg1gtn8lkfAEmsuKy9HKbJpUN074y@X0pY/JZ5LyIi6tsbsS5Og9CS3QL4loWpK1T7ClyuazYpm1M5nh/T27acRzrQ1oKmCoeGHZAW5Voq@1tLXZD3PEPkbDF1IWHEx6d/rpJCz7a@Lol4AeV5tsaPbok9F6tKeGi5wgXpJZfb5@@iSww3ZULHm7FOSG@@dZaL0v6syGqXJKLt/Y6LqE6HcPS@WNWyN0Gryxnb4W3zDT8xVpc3OVLuoul@Ng1pjSeA7LMHmgpQ2Nk0OstUr7eQxMZ/mNtpJmDv3XBM8PoKrN9o7suwtgEvmDjfWkNOSIsTRwb9KsJ7vNDPcXCnaS@7zoOHKz6rUTywUgfGNxmy22ccjFhgbtpuFq3cK6euqjwHTRdSLYwxrGeJKBTnRpzL3iuBPh03oV2nY7unm671vm7OAf6Hr193RbWm0OsPXSG9tAY8n3j4du6zgH0OOE2dm4rOpR6MMStbOPx0hb3KD4tx7LeB5/IGjmjdJz@yjLt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PmAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjXPKNgZOpzs07yq0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a6IGZNJD9FbtkxArzuXkV5q0fBjfBysa3R/9ogPa6HjFnll1QwdHcuWxvpp1@OzoehiFZwQjvRGfni7QsffK6@n5mQBNLKXKZze5csS6FhXdn/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tiLZWSkI4CuWRkQOBR12W7vM8t0sWyWX5bV6BoLalEkX0pH4Juf@8PzQ6akXlb8F@ir6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491aNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBTTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohx818tTLtN0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr5wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a66gCiLZVduL7oT99anumV@fQs3WERtabODLkG70aD@@rYD3VB@Y3cdLDREW0kewv9OTP5bIH71utsX50PRwR1PouGViCkmOEzFSXRv0hhUxr8/bh8YqFh2IH4NcGXvV3LoznuNpsTm5bptWNyc0y@o/16mO6zaB3VqI8@loPPX8x@oy0J6p6Cz06JT8vXMTgEuvgbWyoW5NVs9UR6ZcQQrzB8WFc500/g3TcgbsG6UMA6ENhDAUzlcQzgMYnp/hhhzXXkGJlPd7LnviRIfk8oq9hrY1skwybXNy@2zOZIKbc4InVoaPHHhCQXmCd/n@h0KQTlZj5Mndsv7iaPId4ztQ3rEzdbsGOkN7I1G1wM/V2At2H@OJDgftpZxHtbSuY0H3Aoe1sst0HXs6kdypfeuoULh1VKigtakIGbDE1/efPk9GqYF2a98lhQb2yBautRsGrhGZaYMgtp6PLscOdImH3E7SEW0VviPNLhpz6hK7fuis0neezWEAeW@FCZj/dPTQ6OKy4Z15f@o8dWwHRqMxMMrRkcHP/C9t9FidEJM9wVPtgJ/endkcE9g1gxCXNvSx0YH2tRau9xmLOOCH@kRfMxTR3CDpf6HrTloxrY7hvqJJv4h7nUq7XKDHxox0i/UEw/ugNOl2uUiM83FLfWRpxcYbO47N78RtM/BQn97OVWAooNv7L5TLuBF/aV5gpX62XNXDM75LxOhxoxTr6uoaHcfi91v2JNkm3xOgu6bhKU/QxgH5FXJMAunLu5WHFG/lIQvVCCTZM92jRfrVqsYCpDr7gC1AQ93tOrgS5jtu2Z0TMUxwB5sO9/bzjQMdQPwMOJbenfrGQu8qljXqjOi2VmGItOaR0cFTQR2y5jHRZzcbk88M@aYMIju6QgMAAbvCTl1giWegjSTvHraW9KhlrJpjuhGnXrtcTpt1JNs0um90nDVzCF@LuemlcKiz8ik518xVR7oRzSIrOp10X9mTlreugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xum94OzKysWA@ZjgxcZF5ehVkrujrekCrrrF5PD5mra0i@rT/gJaHdPy4fSrtrJU8ED/@HDz5RYBBuF3KB6RFgXXev4EPhp67tP96HAp853qRvzg6h3HgKYB07wWrlIQk8eM9A19a6SkDr2VOLzz4MIvuuRj1SxySywixJFrHriSEZ9plEhuBmN2vk8ENfyi5a750YPcm3g4ArDdKT4PxXGM1/rlhAjfJG3OypKhyxs0LO3/65CrnnAWcAecuZSGOPnsrYe3bw5PBEHnvqyvFpd4inI27IcUuGFbRSJjIl9Up3I@udfDtaz/QmyoNjVdp7ciBjhDX45isaEjxwZW7psXbeM7DiquhrtSAMNSarBcTHJ0@fpBZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47Pk7jSZNPjlcGR1M/gt7Rd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfk@t2l1cB33XJHTOkgnBmijQIyPuV2WO4WrrjM2eifzsfEZDJ7Iwb33zL6wtpKf6mfmAHshK69FFHVUVpYLuWRkZzYo24YbPte156k5Rm7ZpYfCH2u3o6DkkFXc7Grp4bYV/@tSDMv4OxE@LJGauUmtUTvCiu79fQumquo6PB/rfWhXll/bWMsRVq0PW87ZeywlG77yIoVe0gSoSjLv3EdelEbAuhW84fS87wnOztptMLcBCL0LKzv8uWHPdVuitazbxIsKpMZNbbdG@YbxHgtS4Q6fMzRWvnKNL9xSzxJdcibvyPjEjSTZ23twcFeCIx@Xt8f6@NPn7JnuoRGS2yNGS2y8R4kXktErCeet0ALe2uXUngugtFvhDcar@3OFHetuz7Hns7sX4egMKg7tZFw4hIVvFMmwzJm5aqzq8nmtZ6u3Gd2VNz/E4cyX5OCocRof0Ltv/zNVzWTI9BA@1Qx/vaNlgg7OEujS52jPLhp0chCyhi7KLTJ4JFdqo0@MGW5H4bPBq5T6leNb4Zaxr5hcP5zcFla6JSx3S343wtCTZeWMegvA/C1hLC@HwU8c63zoyHu6a3gr9h@vLNBtFSnfUpFyhDv71tJpYdF3rxfx8eiC/1hJrSfGxM2Nh07HzK2sw24fjUyyp2gs/Wa4v51Cd2l7y8Dxj3zw99X5nU@NlRk91d@sDiBOc7oyCJigMZzSkYibwcsLpB2QeQ17YHL7iuyBM9mnt1sUs/DE8@q9COb44XS8vsTAG/GTFNfZ@VLEz0Fnds499gCPxi3E9BW6P@6PW@2/TqZl4cQgmhl9fLIbUNfhsaJFclyU4otnS954eHRyeBzxc43ZbJ3SK83W6ZArQxa5fnqSW8p2u/7ibAWy1p83AnED@HH4XCsHcWb3yfFNloDq23AysoKQT3R7MWO61GA9Z0InDVcGPpvPaBvlypYe8l1sq8Lc7grvJcUeBmTThLw9pd1Gy/rt9jqqPDG@oLUHEIPYhIslHKhveMmY5YZBCSnJ2o7qnC6En6XiHo@Hpj1bGTRal4Z2kSZeeau7wS47tpxz9iS0KrSOPWirgetnhr2OOa06rCiVs7dLYdlrItW6duFfL/Ef65rkwTpB7RrPwA0Rt3ETTH/UVR4FL59pyTvjf3IcRL877p7l4Px9z5yO7o5MYFOpuyO6t7C/6wDNFdH4AWCgn6jxeC/tm//hB@b5MWVPDiz8JxI2FC25/Dml6JlrNLGc2EQTo5t0vhriXl6yDf9MMwSIwSlp/xQ3WiI07amBx7D5R1YmtU3IplZT82W2g98vqoAGlaQc0YvsvQV5NdjmhX9AuVJRr9hGjYkVkflHxEPzzdwEMcBF46lQJyadqmxzAiGbwfFmRl/TYJeMZmVADVTzGXiTlaihh6p/AByKtHnx7ODZ/vHJ7snz40amdeUfEA8qYduQW2CG4qNsT4S6@2gDaY8bJCfDBBZkR1/6wNkcL6gXw68HLVettlS1RaXEHUyzeWHbikJn5BXpCsoniTw3CkWeBV4cdlBjah/fPEKFH1enU/fQRBy0SHlCm1VYZlXGYx0kl03bD7/@sS0KxY@xVfBzbJixb0MaCHHgOD0/R89gd19Bjo92D548P9pnQQEXRHNu9ibDWjnPTYxzux3QTn2TNg3WWNxPEoe2qtXij@KAmLgcZxWyakDmvYHOIVqAHbSH4KfeYolNgg8YjIeNovznbypXcRn3vychbjwoVByyBZInQtnY2GAnQCTs4dHBZ/tHDMu//5C8EUUIgp3gkeo/@1GPfyAjMHkUfIjOHZGYQSZjhKhZhcDWwMIcAuKcuu54/efo6IMUZHQg/BJG@CkfQaAPpQDdnpO1wmuW7JJkXIp/Ps83NBhkRCQUGNXHpRY0Guh67Mz0TDR5gGXoow2/ZWLH3Vlkt1Jmu/itPfyin05fa4GiT@0Jt5PlW8uJAaXJIctJs00qLP@2ixiJGN/eAGLvGCCBMs82QZ6ZVNgroERczqhwkxiSVI/fSBKArpBLQqklEvGG0T9PabrKu1/9J8qgysA9Afd3fPcs8wDeftl/64P7V7j7hYKEdtNI4KIs0QKhYU@/BrwgIf4R95FPDNrcDMkCcWjLMOCrzBxBM50R1jE6z4HfJWDHCziJxmfQaEBu0GK@@RGen@G2EmhZtKIoSFKoFcl0@MOY8Z2Y1yyMFvKFnKpAIaWzACB9EmCAR8w5wGSyAt1EODPHtZcgaW9vbzMRp0aMWqHKW1bZtF9kxZdhQTchrnA@xMI1GKSBJIsUEFb3k8Hgk1KTmBS5V1yNI@PqOTAqUTiOXvhu@4gQWQKQxXFkoI35GX6NcgICg28pt4Pfb4x8LmbTBySpMCaRKykKvuGOT50JkA900sUHobjhDtyJzEdANEHp8W@0koFapEf5Zs9anDcPvkvj9zUZeQAHlc1cH0yjbSt@jiCOEURFXEW@jResOWnaLYXTJgMy/eEKYrbB/UvKYA3N8nrv3jRPmrhuXBSRxe4f2w7OAT2CyrCEpmhZRS0kF1XK5VZWya@Rnw1UB20gXUJ2wKaAZXQN85Uz9nb39g8@OXx2fMMEJ8WMX48GfL@@nWpKcrrRCh3xaLWWm@TBI@X46YNHQUMsCl2IcGNg/H5N1NtqspjaRZCLo0LXq7aqhNdrt77En3NjAtfLm9VuKxolulEONfMB@dJ2fekRHbq7nrlWWoWtfP62Ii3gKRHQe/zE9I2iJpIXV43Wdr1px@I3KWFFR3gRk7ewE4Cr6W1tKkjsNyuHFQu/nnyC36Xzon0xu7oviptZtPCGBhsmzunCBp7vEQmI1DfIBlikICtB1LW975DL6AtLjRr/ujM3DRc1fBUpcCFzG8YjoE6CD0UjF1nYmfVNrA51b2iZHSEwOMZNrQYWIUMrq9xYWCIp@F8r4Rkn/E9HzyozmfbmJZLI7QhWmt1mtTWAlxSgQ6N092wK6vEzZ8yt19MejIdG4DpygP0@nPI5G4N9Mh1BvD49jgxaDwPOLUFiwGQ8LCqXpYBL@EZbZyk0iwv5NdB0q19xedTLJ2ZJeWjMeuYAeHsimQaO9pGqtlho2BUrTYZc7bhIbbZohVu74sd4Dj6K9g@y7jtbFEBv6LJp94xZIn4eT1ZakD/6x88/P4snxVW0RFaGfbO7vevmhsPiF9XbOYk@8XtnYMt3Fbcol29yCfC7DpibvQs@nVUuy0NPoE8h1lByP564T8AJYkSiP9LHLDG1uclAmdFropmw02RLTapzc6Q2S6VIoYIHBciMUvbJxcfvhG7PWUKp4dcywdeze/h4Y45ZQ5XlFrgpkyTbxE/a7YHEhUY0kwLowJCkQmBrSEKgZkCJeCeROYFDGgyHuPAgw4srgukLX7Rs4CBOqNasfo9FPlG4LDmK5XLFb9BlrlhmQH032aGsANgbfC6Q6wG7vjUhwBmov7IQWzDymxwvRvnGeEEe@2aIoDixiAnhwDoRA1gLA7/doYu/xL4NfQXkg0rl@cmjdimpiCw0ZzRwzR4ua3Er@KGK53@3CLqpshQ1XuUa3ceYDA1Htrm9JLRf@Ig6jHiNpcaiaPCN7wbKsregTVW9ler9hH4rQMwcDgD@sc92AA6NfQbzXSvCVjP7n/40hsJGYlNVT9vuWSqez1ThplbzLM8@2mxK0mYjU7u/qYMWNXk9a4JOrmzlHp4Zw37vYKA0RZFlWU5Rti4uLuKPtp6ZL/KsIPVMrfB6Nr/KFrKvZ1dZtfT6dKwWGvLrWUss1dKnLfbs2Rdv22@T4uxs/lpsJrTY3uGlqOZQ5Y9Vyuxip5CNnZZB/YR8GTtlb@A67TP8J/ebXsSto7vTBxU2LrJYswkYV8WiqCiNeAv@Sd1/CRdX/Bt1uS7vtN6@TTZ0fTKbM9M0x16vBz9nCBKkljxmoC/fA07PEyisSU/SoPAazfo35xPyjM12jcFguq/XNTwRLN9vV@fm9NHk6Tc@D67neL05iiR7439DN5VKSFJjxTxFpa3nY/g13j/78cZV@uJZe/vPvjVSjA18HOLjO1dP0X2s5j/a2PjowYNcLq1pGnc/@8azn9/d3c09TOefNfI7OSmzsf2nf7KxoWnbmrLR8jy1FW@cnn4hapmcKP/Z78Tbz5593fPq2f/zm2/rKt6KcDtjReATcGWZCk68l@Cnooz1vlfsTQyoXI3N6a8dC/wvNpha3yn@l@8dvo5NYnVN@dyF5yT2OlYoxbgTHPCWDd7OYvXYNkYrXMXmSq1WA2fxv/xbSF//BOBgyHwbbvV8AKswj9WlGiW5jNUL4FA1DfL9v7/5zUgJOZuokRgXXPdZAy4xV9TEnRZcW3RtC2gmUsooShDPngwnhsPU0j31Hr6Y8AIP20B7@8akGcPvkbPD@4wdNVKpVEtuS3DJL2iSSFFVramq94AdSB9t1WrSFuOGMLPZ/D005p2kKa2BAyOmce/zf4grtsqz@jODOxJihY37Lx/W61CnbD27VU/R5Xck6lPFkug490WWZi/joII0Wi@fMG69ty5mSpqYTqfvt@l9hriSZiEl4cXvsVjog12WXfdbSgJRfN/Yh8eL7eP15//bn3//z79Hf9@n339AO5p2z@wrWxDpDLpEHa77lUq3XhfrrnjRxPc60FGmUqqUlPZVM7EFHKh1xNTMx5fxfDZ@zL8VrjLWTFJquCjbup89vtdjC@8696lH/fwAHpk8mF8Lcixhjdwh1m7Eg6HV33EsNc7qLQkFoprUUAv5lsRT1YOrzBr3oZlErVgWW3Utrx2y@@0Zv9hw02NODDTDQoBHv7z1Rd3qYcjirR71itWDZPVFnA@NF5ZXiDUaSsugASHwY/c3KhulSqGiKe36@gtIM/pKUQ3DeObFzmLhxTEbWyA0FpLmdb@gKcIXFlAw@5B4IBm9D/OlVsoWVLHqu7Q2E6tAJFpW0gZtMaOKYW/D@X24NuCP/uEKX/G@QT6@N0W5eW2wirqlZZX8R4V9DcfXO65oWQUYJ1i30@m86XZA6tD1jt7V1Yk@1Wf6XJ90pp1ZZ9Kddhl2meUZ/ayTd0rOjHEClKVYNq9uxu4RUb9tbLAjzoVaLBVczdSd13NZbvtOcjj4kyRnFhNi/wBXXdVUtgXjUwZuIJSRE3Rm/FNVgcVA0Lpovd1qvN2CDlpPbRNzbNUlv5TwkNv3Wynp6qoB7mrV/9@uh84qXdwFlWtdpVLbL@ogfbyoN1IA8oUPUpYYAZXb9dY2hYSZ@bn5wdstkF@k1HZju@bs0U@mDiLFc0684NxvAeDtpcLev5@SwXUfANQ3oT8mU6lNSdrAsbHhjxUQuVVPBbXCMiRAWri4@Bl/oOhBL77avqpfNbavrra34X@b7lf@E3yvtm/802NxrYmzCG8ha2k2lHpTafrMogXvslJHH1lpgqMOT4jXyGqlVgMdcMmt/zb/5fTiHvpgkVsylFqIbbGtGFp1zMa2hNjLd1/@L/hrvvvy91FeZPBnVITYBXZrZQu1zTJXOuHG7Kc2e8ovG9z4C17RBz2e1tHT5jcbF6QU5aXMKnzOP6GWCkkZB@C202@joQiZvYSoN3gfE7VSQWyn1LnGYttioUjs7uduXPF4/B@91MrFOJ@oQUsHLz3Pexop5aKcELmqZVRJvaxzY/78uys/t@r6Rz@37hJil2VmVAA/XY9xzAgxIKSYokgSjFj17RHuhce1EgnV0rPaF9LzXQnnUfQJrYR1@RxB7WC/Vi7X@TLP5jPqNlsPt@Cuwv/@BtSDNfsQt9mvdUcgATf72bzWRNPvManzGv@evME/dtLFv6PX@MdO3uDf0QT/2NMO/p28xr/dDv6djPDvwWv8e/oG/54P8K/5lWxWrYqbF4SalFpWrzZnIqGoGtupN78ycecVy7AbZq/lf9UomyuzZKz5FWOG37avcM9@/Cff/da34rVaXIrTt2JyquMyNVkF7EONvHj1flyI1dimuqlmrEw3o3bUDjhMlnFZZpgZqj1QVNoqyxgsM8/MWWbkqD1wGfCXAZeZ6bPMgGXsjA0RIRRck3Zmgq4@PAbw1wdALvyZuLWzo2a6DDKyUGijz0wieHBdtptCg8WZ@NIAXVNW5YxcMFv4cZ6G@PJlU9lqaeUSk5Go5HbjZTPeEpsiGmzXyjnWmRsbzZciDM0ZkRMf@rCY54ECW40pzabC0QQYICxeXbXb@58@bLcVHIaaT53Dxf/h4Sj6euv/6NB5euiMHPg/PDyErmPUU/dTwKDv368Bw/YfO7F6dadZIbYfsP6Ysr3TrGcldBdSwM019Et94LWACM/6RlOInydQ9zhH9aP6@Xn1rEru8@AVHO3qIkIQjTv8J1znMMQF6sg5XGfn6KA3dJ5/3gxd3KF8fg5enzPQu8J/UPCir/8V/s3/tv6fPmdJlmi0komLq@0EXUn8SyYvri6u/Hs9mUj4L4lt@EMPeMckF1d1dFKkC3A1EslW8uqK@8E9kdzmAOuQzXad0i7iwbAQC7OkbPkt8V/3CVn7VzNeBbmX69b5DPWjmFhl@mJfTbM5y2SS1U7wLQpcJdYvafNCskofItzsNNTWn/4OfW9kJ0mR8rlqVd1i/EXLadVqLngrlqrVUvCymUiUb171zI5aAP0jl0smq1V42QnAZuAV0jbY2xSrsSbcW/fu8UxK2uVlADObK6QyagZTBznlIVvD07s@w704OKRPdQCrycfwGzmclSQy9KEf/JhcXKyI9@4l/I/U7@wm793TypnLy9BnPAYvdcmr3e6ZbruN/tnLS7Et0j6Ych7eM6XLSzVTTqnxpOMmPsWvEEJWCUllH2l1yrUMbFzLFSHYL0B@e7uQq9cLOfAplOJJXFNvYPFbUN64GK@KsQuqg1oqcg4oVtE7uj8I@jIOCuziKkYNynL5ZAIYaRJkwKsY/rnIc/lwk88nATNXIo@plss8apLlColSquz/1TZAKwchh/@hpJZN5baKW/dB5sU/b7bqQp5cvTBq6lXtwqjgrPpVtet/zxnNXRj37mXLgKJSptoU2u2Huye77XZNFEUUlOCGnsTdBbQC4sYbVPN8ucUxUqnep2ZWS3kG7cnjSHEYIVgJkK5oW3m1hEgSzD5aswGUCFxb2mAbgkZPvAlljrkN8AR1BjLvwcV6rMMGeLEBKm/MZBZdzGI8nO7dbhjJ4ZcfGr5SWtLvAh8jvAS/F2Y5icIg/uzJ7t7@SVrbllhMe7S7l9aOnz@IqfiaX7xTcBbfj/Z3Hx4@hwTPnuzvHu9/fPDZ/vNn4O@x88UVMH3/vnhGXSvez9nnwiv3jW4YujE1jPb5dHr@mr0yzbYJjWlNoVLOwGWe0Ya6jPVFvarw65qe/uqV7o7pYu9@@O13P/zv3v32d9/99rff/fb3f/Ll978Nvx/B77v8@d1/U87j/Sdf/rPfffdbvw2e/wF@fwS/H//ky1//Jv/R@x/D7z9F/P7Y/0Xi8Z8AsH75J19@73d@8uWv/AB@/9L//eDm71d/vPr3/V9Y/8N03/vd2@N899/C7/c4rCDud3@L@@HzRvzf4vF@5Qfv/sW/4/9/6v@h87ff/Ys/xpv/8k9/8Kf/6d23/r2mlf70X7/7he@9@4VvvfuF77z7hX@svfv1f61morfffff9P/irP/y9v/rD/5H@f0T333uf/3c/@Kd/8b/@xf/@F3/o/34Mv38Hrh//xb@HrvK3f/BD/P/eH/ztH/0Q///nf/W3f/Brf/vL/xM5foM7/p9/@W/4/a9/9T/@zW9@569@/M2/@bUf/81v/MFf/R@/8n/9@n/86//@9//6n3wLPX/jx3/1R7/8l9/69l/@wj//y299ueb@7VvvX76H/5f/AD7vX873gfM@9fpQny9/pvL8fbCxyAXoBKj7l979@i8Cgf8Lxt59@0d4UAx@a/5/pKkU50f87f8DDu1mnTEkAy74/dq7b38XUfQ/AIrgP8TXd8KXpRD@8p3FC6D1N1ck@qWffPnPf4feYkalTqs2OHaXtFJqC/SbrXLZH7/9BR1I8ovL0EIAfk7fQQ61FPYd5G3vfvjNd7/zj9/98Dfe/fCXcfCWcuX0blpS71gNg4j594iHEQvvEw8jfoH5p2iKTUp9AW/sCz/wiy@@ENqXCp5IvH8Jvl@QF78YD8ITi35QEIb@eISRXbKo23dmfOem7xvmzFjj5csWrreCH@aeItljKxCN8lk2S/kFmzG@rIP@EGm2Rc4Z3skXg2cC3hb/C@dMYKmZP90Lz9TCSQ4/nZ8Fdwp5yCY1CxeTSFZjXDra4j60Tkz55soMazCbpWagBIMDckhB0AMQx2u1FCas8fLAKy9avcSoKKlUDeqNqXmadLuEIGYPCAqkrKWOWHurNuMJUwivHqAjJaDXkahqYqpUewgZ1mYPGcJC4AT25ctavVSb1RHcW46P1Cz1gMqEwGqpWf0tvNcIJqQTYg/fQlFKtVSqXsIMsZK8edJt3kh5qhzVPcVSfhvAE7f779xn7CNRLYl8kWADEcZj4z21iI0RITqEN1NbfnXoP3DSb4sQvkFZ@bkwHr5DsukOF1cxAsCVJFmWGfxw/X2H3YfgGQeVomzhkeIQUkQRRAGhB8P5oZSQovZN0QvkH6ttffCFwLAym5ubQqwuZsVDmVCnKMw9rdDZB9wOiOpFhYmFsojeBh0ECcoC6auU/2YcF9bijANmH6X47/79LfYRVJOeCz@BSamsk3NiHMp2KiVqAL/upIQXoJYIQKcE6FKQZzVayEsJ6TRjci2GYezw8NAvBHm8qAkpIHMtq@I7LidNp9MYpJDltJxO@0@ZnuQh@w6ZQv2nvInIpc90M03LVUF7qjL0YlFVRwUVGD3fvn0LrUL7qyoHoHwyf6uVlitRIHhwwyyWNQ8ODGm5ssA1c6YWcowlaIoVriRLCizBtpIC35XPCxFcibhWKsUpHmBfTmwFO@8KKpEDTq/G6ljQ4OIqYSmfDAL3Dtne4dOn@5@ejFstJhj02XGjPXadruF5CQzb/fQhP5GhlQvJWKOBoE8qGjIYYb@SIWZ88PDo4LjCeKX9JkhQwaq0rupXs6wKsfH48@2Yv/NIxC/nOeIx3iuLuiW0chaSxupCrGugZoEL5qgAV1lVeOoNHjgz0OnTophWC6jZJWlSmQk/70wZ2nXlRmCgT@E5DXl7mzAg1C8kWrpAJ7RWQajX/T17TBXqx/snkODkkKlaRhbqX7CZjBlKV0LdqlmGPZgMN3Hzm9jMiJE6bTYyafzTslm4q7lCWs0XWxsb1oWEeTap2S5wF@MVvF5IWI2vwsWErwrsq@AFF@SBWxOZvy/04LDqb85DC2oJvkNPVPPQzZICzmNzcMI4elWBupcXgoTYxje@MWH1OujX0sEjIQbcYsiC/WmS2ZOHMjVzb@oaFDpgrGd@ZuInEeWe6Y0tfQ5dB7ARu7q66gOkg0dMq2v0ylP08H7VJZ8OuK9muhCzK5XaWzVXFLTTSuVtVtME8BC2FNwAtwEEQPsIthT@V/Ugk2y2pACnUkURHtlsVsC5Y0GoGAKjvSJvM7WaxGkwm1Npq4iAX9nQZzUtvPy4s48WcbMZHhdDIIANJi7LBGFFHua/FQR6A6Th7jj6pnPV75yZe/eyOImRzWXC2QqqMbuCttnM5rKIceH/v/AAFl/N2R7Xsxl1WxmDUwdnblvRwdkBZ35b6YDTBGd5WzHBOa1n1cy2Mq0LTNjmNlQZmmipiRNjhiabuZ9Y9wyrL@PZoppIGWjitm@TvB4krPdqPadLH2Sv9mTTtg0XD1TzBLmcWHVstO5XQzsfdASdJZIXwqB2Tse@BaM2kNFgjGvrltCTO05vLnuTuYWndCzHrcVBHIwHAQvoBsghOPe1k83mKg3WksfOeEfQ8sVUQ83AAII/tZTW0hvGTrFY6cldy9DdnXwlX0r38ACQv8S1k89UBvIXT588nkzGRwadCtrJlSEBmlhDY0g7pUo@32o0RDHVoGxa@Dlpzp6kjQ3o04bek@CJC2CepJVakLhnurVaPL6TVTVJrWQzpSthgTjEOdawLmDSFNYsjXi/8DlAxXZsYDaVtJ42LwgLlX6/f7V1kVq8CPqFxN8AP1eSnu5chK9VKRKvwqZpyVwEgo/eB3Rf@Gt7FVHLl8Rqo7p4LxbEautKuD8yeqaOh4GamYubqQrAlDnUGGTUZMJVxXWcSaVj9B3XWETMqoUgIi/QzQg58SrMrpnBHC9uZleIRJpd3ISSy4tXYaqgWMLVFeCdIxvQ7hvIrdOm2YZazrX2gQUB@WwHtnMxWuzFCyG2dfRZtl6Hpr7IFbVcPpfXsoVCvqjBeFPOFfIl6GyZQiavaQAlVy6Vi1dA14ryNkafxmN7FwG9V@jjAAm9wq1bNlos@fZT07ooZSVejkSyenUVeyvEPjr6TIMBcu2VgEH3M02q17L5Mriy6NKyUGAmaJqkZaWsKqlZ/L/DoeH/@8fX4F/DO6TKasIJmrz5FIZNGOpt9gRNZ0wcduLgx5MG7IHRXRNjb6jTjuY91/G8v0ecB7p9yoMemtzObBj0WMcvyHkjczJcE@P5eITWcgz3HwzC/qgDBUR2yCM8gJtrOc6qCEX2/NmaWj4NLbsDMrhpd4h@dPDx45PI82R/d@@xUGAPDj99eO2R9yPl2ZP9Ryfha5GHBknzIYif33/y5Pqr/8gdPj/qTx0Xf8Kjw@e5xS30wgOzQg6u5UihNwHxb/hKgiVIFKCI5YuBQxXwmMU9UI7v@c58YeHMoPNzfhrY9MJt//xgeEU4CY4I6ww5bcdgXW4UCbV1Mljoy/JqsSwIY2Y756yYYT3HsnSXOf3@BngOdTzuaKBAa1lIiZj1ueNavXOzZ2wIT/FkZVnFT49jIYTHAGQ07ZKxCxBm0PxtDz9Uj8tSHWtqsOmYrfWEB3qh0zUHQxiDz50ggtDRdQa/D70gvRG9Jrd7THge5HcjxLoZXQCdriSKe6L4WJ/o9aqXqVTu3VOfuWJZHMN4rHsDY38GJMueQxfS3XlanMhi7hFrD3BVw3LGqH944wYI7GWt0drJafVSJp8t/fVv/ujv/uTXBjW1mdnLSNs7T5/kK8DYQIZlJKb6oqxMSo1WLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLgz5YLINKkFFLaqGUL6vpUq4MMkiuDKH5ctEXhJVA8lW2KgDW7uKHsLdJL5KHoADxRUj2JqEnWUwP36dMNCCNKKAKOqGD41tmDYZPpmZYtsgAos66LPbo0V7m0SNRfIAvuIljLyOKPXzJlzKZ4gNRNChkr4TylOjwNCU0KShO@Esm8wAwPOUA0Bq/KA7xZb@Ak2miaOLL3u6jR5hPH180TA/RTnkIf7GClyJEs/EF5HMC8DqEBtF2eT45Kug@vmCWGPKIh@xBmCh@HBQHQ454NA7gcVDT3V1RPOAvu7sYskfVzvOCfg1fdukSRRdegPBFcQCOgQtdThQ74ETyF8UuuLpzHfzwo@NosN2e6KI45@hBBInijGLr3VNRbAf@mM1nfmnyiN0Kvai81vfppYx/oqgFhcZo2fAlK4q58CUHdXv8@DN9OOkZA37NXf7sQk0fP87q5my6/6jz8cedwaDjznf3Pz7CoL29xyCLzKduZ9DxE3bacDmQau@xpp@O5tcvqPVBu13RrZVBX2u3c7p9Lag9bxtYQkj1GkrmXwPMaNTeg6C9x@37@qpFZALYxp4/gmcHrwcjeD7QOzwouCiInrNOR6wi@StKMyGgtoDLv9gdT4GT2umR3nWdKr7PaiyTRoFl3ihkWlUKYCOQ@jPVKwzvJ/Cu48xP8mLemNUyrdqsVtT4LqR@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pV0HaF04@zuKTusIR6b@sNS3ya3NFAAxCbOzuS2FBbO5paqhSKL7amopis4H0nW6y8SWTiGcbwlmwUWzvFfCRFsZjSFa1SLIIcBjiZwHDewQmZdiJxbuinySSWlqYHoApUVzaneprVfmKWntV4udg8WZ3V1Co3VMwyN4D10Cr@tDtxXA5yAOBmO5kKrr8nRLVcEqEAipJIJkOmB9q6sNgA@vnXT05PTr4gga/uz1w8cw3kXlX/9ePHe/LBYfCG9uzlRyiHOq68h1xrKYQLpIHXCWgg8mMYQkGbC/zwjKDrWPI@7ZsDYTYICCw0yb5tWfnk8RKc46FzznNGEwtVMlBodw2G5v7NHtNrdXDpPZagUjE9eU6Dd7ter7VrI7JCAFUMUn2NkS38BZgDj5c9NPxAyS/w3Jwf0K5lrqqd2iw2AzjtGpPUlyOn91JLdas9tPL/oPYAE1fb8OxUjZrhuo4rgi4tVvs7dm1qe3rfeGa4aNLk4HATRAk8TJfoMyO5yZr7GHsP9ZQrqe4ye1GyT6ejhC7VO8llL5yVCz0QOYmvB5W@oPOduEPjqtqvscQLiPoa3t1NlujJD5I7uSrg6QFrJ8Er87L/ss80VshVSc9IICzoSoQfrLfOkrX61@DBYZ9WKlAav6FPASpmBoDNHgVA7LF5Ve3WLJaQ2IwlCUm56qDWwOSXeNuWRLElSY3LllCXpM@FOvTX6jym17xphz4QwzIdVcsUqjPwU4u56hCaV38xq7q18dQ1qha8@pN5/CirXgWkAu4AzJvLxLtf/GZyW8rXuF@VQF1aIHa05XZtVrXR5CQQRi1bg4BUI5dJgwYPt2IaxnytkFYL6Ww6l5aK6AsDfjqfBk/QcEDASFgJkTExnZllZDWtGmo6kXlp9l4m06cJkFsIaSyZnjj79nTEwAeaCmmTXuEJ6ElpWxZoXj2H6dsSESuwjCpWDLA@ZGMzPURQR4ZuUYpkUmLZrYS1mcA4myfT8X6jVansz8Zfh6CE9HqnkCpmUm@SyWpiI1nzjNdCvSrUkb1QrccbQLn@PCfzpqMGtDK41KJWaTQ6WMViJp3NZKF2ZvtysC3WxVY6s1FQoYmuGLENxvlGdOoPJZ6F37iNkrdlQNOpZa0qyDQPly1pUlnJb@UzfC6QpxTGPntDTLJEUwyObSfi8aIWjyfjVVyF2BD9aWfgacTP4sBd4/fUHRGEMbEiljWMsGCNdDI3E5QOxLErAaVClgPF9kK4urjargtfEY7xvOW29gL/ii@e7h7i31fAqwyvpRdPnx8@P3wkMIU2esrtWHWjKlfbVXiR5Pp9IVZhDDhp07cppWww9qFbSFPb9Rf82cSzAwBXIDPSDdairV2GiVob@wztFeywONRBd0cNTcu2GloRxj7gpkFUTVOruEYTw9MJch0aw7uA8m2n6njU72tsPtdTUqDq32NskNoUCD2x6/MAu7XdwdFusDttd2/1bMHmTMEJ6tWBdZCHTk9V/8xOMdMWqzHWFvP@4bimIIq4BS52EY/Fr@AvFg9SvngTHPQpiNXTTHn7xlGgcngUKAcx0PblthC7T4cdNX7YkcXC4464lusvw2RzBZYsB6skX4nfj8XjcVyOqDDvbSy2qhKnVTGeTceL6biaZvfjxUKWil99I@b8moSlKrXFN9UXVGIiu@Ak2tdeakDxMdsJPEDhw8k4GJHzeZz@jykvx943tFL26cGh/dB9FDkV9aIew89/S3jAq1p50d44VYHSs2L2NB1j92N0KEAsQ0k07gE4PmUqlAJwHVcrUDwh1ty43HBwYYeF2w3f2p98nbFxPJsDrDdrsVkt5@9jV@t1Sd3W0M5ckVVgAOurBSlzWeddtE4BBQ1C3v3iD3Kz7RK8axkV3jUtn9LqdXVLY8nY@N2Xv48mgy72P9t9wuK4HPB3f/I7WvHv/uRf0Y65@BUtEWjZYgxiolMtFGMXF@OLiyu4eFg@1orxQuWKSXDz5So1VldULWvbdpVVFF3fKqZy2n27qvhx1aKajHlSzN8kmi3kpURCVaBUW9lSJglhl35MLVOCt2ChjEcXC9AiUIH9IzOvqfe3d6B@O9mcVt0A2lLDg7Qs/Ns2vDIqrE9fXjIGL916bzAwNXIpCqu8ldj2W2mbvcVlqrfSBntZq@N2BxWP3wbLOFt4HBGXMuP1lLIVZ6DwsXrjqnrVStE6EKjFLwxjy25eI8/mBp5HWfbasuHP2PLoDxMFHh68Bm/G1itPTGwlFaXXE2@S/bbB8nUgmC1lcUiYbQWrO/xPkprJd7/465pW@Ls/@dXL9mX7Cw2U5nK5oGqxn/50e2pPPaNX/ykAuMVcTKD4kuyLdl3QESrMjJvVNP1UoUPugq4@tVE54PED9RkVZgaClTmwjR6pz8IZCoPUuG1usbCXoGhbaE0iTcoFWQhLVgUhkMK58uAOummCwbbQFmyjlRQuhK9iEMgaDBSQqvDVBSjwGIF04XTbnjV1x3SeJ0Hp1Faa3YMkkMNX0RjkBlnB8AcqCTi2snUzKS@yR1gjwZGNDM9D05IwxgpfhSS@wWxrzsY6GmzBmKYNI6OMUaicFNBrQN4tyNviCdrkm6Da8whpxkvHE9mgYAhfBVmJsGCCCMXMbYhQBUb1VUAA1CHhAzZbbJtlk@zCTKWqC7uVV3jyAC1r6oGxCAGTIbQeGicJElcxHniBYoOfaEW68FsYJNiIZwCEw@AbFWqgGmFyekOplKy5vDcogEWW0xJUNXbv3qJUtZrZSzKqEcI/Ncc4rUftYK8uKwAL1MqPehUxzdAiaDXwDckOMJ6i4gLVSdwUaDWSlIn4eiUI8P/eRIsUea2pKKCKFfDbi/eKLqAMEiPaeRt22XaNqVoxycLCd6HsXSoUHdkPdeXm7CNZ@yIIvIIS/jQWfAAJmNZJdKrUp9vr1kIYaBJT/PoM2ozjzMC38sGtwiHzO5gEqcNUUBXToth90wUtjnZQBAYpE1k1ickWBjypHMTHtRzDLfr5JD4oFcZm8NTRsKKfzwYZhOo60KDe2LHJEiNZisLzEUARwKN8I3a82FP7HL9W5rcNJY6WyCMDdkj5WGKyLEmfeae0uIWh44K2H@AmzYyBzLqjHtPKLEGERsb27BBckhJRgTugDCCOO5YxgiIdGwYdqvMqijIAAXHaIYuDT02gq@EjE0Yg21MecgQr5@apqZyg2WDJ6ePZO26/JYYyJXY/vlvCt@5nOc4ps8xTg8@AJ5as33gM1CGQ6NOA2cUPEFvBbThaNo2zMiAnUSz4FeFR5M5SOpJ2IzFP3nxm1Y1EG1v0ksYbE1rFMs50O4Jfui4Ffx7Am3uB/SyyAgXvcshyDd9yTi2ONjFCk1CCbwmsRkaoZFxZGSfEmBhY0EKnMHaNM4YavYBjDDDNbmCLBnsx1ParNABQ34OehYY1J24FLShBSdxeogtdz2fwNvuIZTUBI3LzZr4pMoCBTV9bhg5hkBTr4U160DAyLScgX4HeOepBGNru8MkP0wfUjW4yerogb7bhg8NBh/KqMd4tgpd85AV7B9IzVX0DAgtQwhUl2UiIKQCbEpMiBx2mv56cU7tAvKTCbkJKM4TgoxqgkKigI8tBy4mRz4oJEPBA9/i3J3yzm@fn5zLZgp26pmx4@Kktz7F1SxkPTJCxHWVijMb@R41N/Ji9D3fhkvgX9uTxcLwzQ@m2Vr43509B6Hs1fzNTIt734jg4nuGXpAYjshuHBts8IqhHJn2Frpvw91Zx@tNa6YuA/ipIf1IpfoVAGEMws/Q83U0DsHSne5run/eqfsAZdUgADq1oBJ5oodkNXkZe4DLH/TCGM0E@GgZ1rFNanwZIIp@@XmTNaxjEnAev/vvYnEEi2zhnu66rzxMUnsTYSMCJOYk9bA7DPoWAE@1yX3BzweasMW8tJZ@FyWFQC3dnuGgUTri4HSi3HY3hMx4@g/AZD58tMg2ybcxaXCRDryusDlI92hINYiKYeRDnittZXoQQZJDHQXciP4w5X/K7gl@3RqkDfPM3aMdaQBhAE2NAuJFQGi@ajWbL9ozzrVZKGQCxi4QIaHEA3WgRTs97oRuxb51ZY8db8rLRhCyMSn650as79KmB0wrWMWwgIgyOLxOtfg5G/jYSLhD4FQYIKIdBIIoGu5OEmayGtsopEAinIS5wzAvW8AvTIunLD/L9QFziqOeIjQJqRQChf1glKCaEsKDn8A8rBtzhc9eBOEFcib4FN0Lrc/FWHDB5ratwXlOlRoqUSpKCYgLaUVytXa9KEA5N0bgWFKnmld/@0eJvfHDx@9AvVpeeCJYPGFUh2lVw5yaIEH53Iayyei3SrlACZUu3DBdGrn0un/qjNWSzpQRqBs8Hq@Cdm5PuMBFp/G6Stw@dDxVtsRKSwrxWgyrOa7xb8n4RoJQjPEzm@cnmASH46TkDARiZlckMP9ksmmxWq3HGwWZrkp1HCjmjQs54Eh57tqaQLT8ZaE8HwfCCzdMC6RS3looAT@XDKIhBY5F5@pmBi/2v0DImLpn4eS54DlGBT0MoYiOddVsrc29ECh1hWtcAICHeANDj32iuCNcZniqFbyGP4qgMeBR/88mA8wogMGLBVW49OhESGenAIPCLKRoHoO@KqYYgqjTtjX8Z/hPTgWfwU296ZpZjqsuemfS1v38QzxZiNtJBI9KHmskhQ0ZN5rntm12NyhwxtjsFBQekus65wxIrhG3wV6Z@UqVjOR1lpOOmHfxyK/eVx/NkoD/gwhG7P3Ym@sTJ5SpcaTKJ7Fblz3UGc2A7@MGniAV5kPV6juHZ8Qk0atcZ2KZnpBka9zw1fLXD8D9pIUTlZN/peILgbx/jaiyC5nSFom67jd@Sb7cTuCszWQm3mNMmTSTPeFxA/RdckfTAnnygh@OE03lldCfJu2Hi5xD8ZCdm9zRxOPYDcU52lwEP64L8D6FDkGCY5yw0RzK1jqJ0Z5Kgz3gMnZEzAKlv6skCpr4G/mABGwukj8dUljTTUaWtRD6KQb0k0U3rST/p1z44KfualtCTYXptGcASMtLMvY5jxKy7Irv22ux4siC/4w8v73G0vMe3l5e08Otl5qp5jQd@WNbZxAICRFwUI3t3MbDqwLd6N4qzVJTQG@UqnuC9i9ijTXE9LOkuRN31o8t9oI90@ObBW1jwz9bh//YGDJLvv2/z6dDt2fEc@M0I95cm6Bt9XrD@m4DoB0nkPTezC0n74XvmBXHx86iPUIQAMZYYl41WoqFjjkHt9sIJ5ADwHTSP@9Bu0D1tTqvxwBVlcs/S7FRb30QP2z3D0udGL@HHTEfgBjU@AoWN@NX7VRwZHTE9h@t6CRi7kmEoDOOIdB6psoZk9PRZMrmerHgUM6QemimnEh6sxx@G32DNOMVX47PVoAfE4zGcjj0zcfpzPB/P@YcILP6BNp@P8vGHtyTauLgbIYAHPnqq6UW2ydvY51EirNJ7jAhhXHm5ymgnPICIpqNutuGHoejumkLjRhLVglYWlj/Bs7rFzdtaPEIVAU3yxaj3I8m7iO69aS5CahzYgoXtfdgQcgMyblrpdhNRiNzn1hZz7Bs8Af1ons5eM6q0VzDUMCVxuolJ6jbJF0kBNeMDeP6/3X3bWhvJku41eoq0hBuVKZUkbDAWFrYAYWstDB4OdnsDrS6kEqitU6vEQW3T38xc7BfYcz@PsF9l3mGu9lOsHX9EZlWWJDDuXnuv@WZ9q02pKjMyMjIyMjIzDjhw@kB/AfA8GNWFoUzfcKalc54q/tL1B5bWot@Qkk5QLCoKyTUaVqmUeabiX26jNht3ttmYarORaDOaAckmrUKpRqJJPQoYnvuGoBO0RndIZ3zC3pn@3Ce26X@9vj/EacWXhfZCqe2qhauFEgnkhWChVM2SUF5oLpS2@CFcKB3ww@eF0l/pIZ5bC18XSmZaoMCQfvLDa7zXIhy/Gwulzaxzmxr5n4PQtOstlKIxpTKv5CdThEiBfpPWiCu2Xl93czQMaGFjpdJV4JjQxfaJz2Fc/q9A/5ekWpxuBx9xxvmEC6tFVUwsGtaKIe3QsmHSOcyYySW9mlf3ttnoKyqCZhZpj2fXYfCkhmcWksJIEMNXvtGgv4Qg5GZpNkbKWskeiI5unTiUBznZPlPPY32gmeXvx1T4NG6EM6np@ma8kiBkAB@GJyrfhecUOqY5xgh3ss4MtEDUnxfu6RTGOomLHn17hPisO1mIsM2ZIjJKDNaS6aTD8eUcGhv0B0km4a9wLWjbdfhQTiYluHeiGksFPTPv@Myvdc8gGOzJ79zXHaseUEuIIHw8LpzKLIvWBZbF@BTLOktTlclHKFgyh2Z40PjMWeq29COXE3Hj8lpx1zJk6kqTLLmSYpIqe4jZdemPpPVo81pFJK/v276amjc4a8kCgFUzakXka/879Pe@6O9GoTZEmGhglmI9eymdVq/vXWUnMO/EzU4PID66asuZqRxFLcQkp92BpZnfx2tTKj5MPkTJl0Yj6BPaviFbtCf4Bt0m9xYCC1rC8Cr58vMSvfy8dDehpjWSzpVnlBYPLWk40vEI07hr9@MqHZ81xPjC59t@57sHeJgcYHvwAI87MJwguczy4WWPrVziuU1iW95ApBZLSgQ5X5dGwxy/JHHPV7fRtS292Kvvb@3t7nyiRff58@eOXqPHMX6YtThrjdZxgcwW5NF6MGPbsuQilRQuu3EcH170h6NHJ730lCwRYU3KgE@tGPbTc9zRssyS5xNzl@pJWYuiGtbneBr4CakEVcfHkt3WdB0RQYJR9omvgRj1lujt8m7N4aRJ9XrP7wb1Oi9fJl@zXsUwNOZG3Plb5lH@MhxyXmLJ@HWdSnHwDLW1pz6@rRyqw7dVtX20@Vf1ae9IfazsHiJuwvujjZ3apqL/qrsHVZVK2EgiOyI2lETXraARIOWtWioUnimGvNkfjEXuZDcdeX/gd9XbfiPANdXL0O@@vpAfXi8YrUutKm1HxzjDbHM2zG57BHsLTt9I21goN012h4TLg6KyZ7Sn7WLP2@032602lU1h7ztoB6HxoFOdNo0gyVvjRO6KkoRMjWw6xBlYYYF1TdV9Ko@7GwLji/0VSIwSktqx6SlNuOh/303Bw@r@uwOFEBybe7tbtcPa3u6B2t7bp5/vP9V23xA9aweH@7WNI3zigu/2tmrbtc0KvxAECp5CbIxfLsPRvSh4KM5UaXzGzbc3oOGPfiVPvaHBq2ufHUNDtXDZg/Rp@532b0FzYS11GUJ9gTMqXxWo7Hxl/80HWvNV8CtuOM1VMNsfpI9Czh46X1AvuTWaLOs039b0dKVlL1d0@D6iO1ZIIBSsccyMLD@7ygBnI55mO1DpTdio4OxbQmvwXDagqaFHBBugjMFKWXHir4UF9yWDXKfWGp0@4qBKa2JEqH@g6mtjarKWYoppWxkAhVNHrYfzoOJa9IL4nl4s6WZHQymgnkYvpIB6Ji@gitZgO6KWdYnL0d4lxLNakRe/dAfbfC2snkcvNnzexa5qnGTceEh9FSVORKCRDqd3k1MeTkHLydy5Ssjlkfqs05GJEUjSTZKJcpXItm1UMk3CpoWrBm32Jrms8ZW4AXZCfmsUqmzZ8dQhjIOCXlsS6513/J6YQMWmO8x7ahUxncra77wdJaRjN5lBnxkQyTCTeET1trRWGDy0HtXcmGrR1zaSnBTWmKB9C4GNKQT@CBgClEvsdBq8UrGvLsD0W5qVs2GfOBLntr/b5Ymdm5eNIFFBW21lf2n/9pujiewm9knGTpGxoyH6LRiSWslXma3@kOY4i1VO4QUp2LjoD0ZtGcNssgd848TLHJXGwkat/VxeT7QGOky22Ov3rEbPiIvvaPWMmPIhrTLHy915JL7i3M7E@bQIi90d0PHP@leBdXfm4hLpOsDxCynCfFeOw8/xiDER/TMVy47fFVLCrpbXtzZOcr//7CIvrIgFSctsjA7xHzEm2qLpwfd8bLA4hN6lZ5rJ5xdenqG2tsHT0hKz3ACjfeBFm/Z1r@tr0TcxN55@Dxeiyff88uvXstTKQTLpXN7hRTaWbq46Nk26XOdUaRMQS3YSsiTrs@aNyzAjef0abkMYBQQp6kGOYN8@kS1PixDTu7PLFkkWnbRYD3cE31HrbFERZ3yHO5A9HvmfshvlxXUnHxuUKIucWSOiXQO56DiWWQqvV1Pgtu4HR/L74eBW78VOlofvgrZ1L7Tvwi23eDcsWZYsWA8H@/s9YGVx@0Ngqe/u3YBlkZyGFnF6xJzufCaypr2/xZ@nxo7nHoHB2osTlAio1dplj6@oTVTxrFRwbDCxQnRwuFXd31dp2Z9QXZJ72DI0tRgE7EfqfWxt2@6xsPMipSnaLEfKk3mTsGiLHLTumcwziXeHqNA6iKvpEQmLOHZ5q30jUk@vLKxCsPU9C0RDuSR2X4wMCo814FvaAxKy8aBZHUzN7GZGFp92aBuBa7q5ohvbNvxsYS1rN1IBD8c2INsmyD@HZ8ns8fso@nHJtCMKFiI7ocNN0qRpvaF9wgE1PKCCnpccwXuGxQwpjOxFwc4Y2sHwq5DUsP88QzEjiRIuurAl1rVyrFET/XjeqDlskIhlwIelp/4oFs30wYh4fvPSHlAnXvSyySWIlEwkh31tcwVVP73VSxhTI1ony5FCbs@1ecbm2GB5itNZDXvt7kKPYQu9MikeJpsiaXtvU7m/T1OySiRaMjSf2RnzkSCvLC8//RbsyV6Y6rk/C1vWkEn5OeoOaH8fgwzHIR/vE@fWdl3zPWaAe0gnpvVmwkxUJFVnxpqS6DsvRjZ@hIucCxEyCMWPfLuTrTrqZgK32dBlRbKhc5GpPlhTOOqozJop6t/e3xwE8jfbe/T97clkQyGYDt7CKv9dfxgGsVeeFcfGegX//@S7YDjscTHxZ@oCSpbdmO51tmNvOzF4lV7hI9@32T1pae8kMbt1zVkDN8LHix5SbON0b23yeC9XXLO7ul3bqaonHJqzlTiLTA/TjiV7HrV79yHAMpjPJbB8sA/f47BE/xEOrgFJZGJvvizTxvkmbkwR0pqPOVeTNgvVsrU4OfqtsOH3EPnETT8OVdr9gSryKWx1b9uZdbJeWEvUJ@TCQS9Ltdx0zktzVXqHA11ASoKQ0cR7a8GCp4axlIR7zXkf9lG42Apu5PSMLSf9fHG1sPIixb3ruSO3e/zi1H3SKKcVLb5@rxteDq@bn8/7F1ct1VGDX85uGuPfflVq@Zl6Sm0t/SDxkYsr5TyHpH1O/66qFwXmXI3gK471jJTPnuTCVWpBxfvwtUfK4QfeNJfgITHBpepJ13AhXOxG5e7xymm5Vy6sdY97p2tw8hstlkeLxcUsXvxAqyjJGLmZPx6dYk21T12D3pVCFFLOuapdQxS7htCbd/6w3d@p7L5JnMZBAcARmLb15gN1Sa89B2s2@J54veA6q4/JXAWOTUFBSs2xV1AR7v18nozjmGabMKNRcUmbDW/437GTmit4l4NRn7@YmJNgLfW1/TU1Z9yYCnyiQEWO2yYyJfwLCE5cJouLIXk7FivqXFHUtSJ8Jx0LxDFqsjhMn6TT8CkEotqX6/g0FXqB37gAEsgn/5WrqZcvObs8sVro8SkeTDn8ITtMFE7xiAsQ@jPg2wY0wZp7yG4fKeo@fhfxIG/4jGrEfjJsIJ9iTRFfYP6tvrB/E9d/SQQQws@JzuXpI06teZEiKb6DfLiAgG7JjT@uGeBWKYMyh84CtrRXjoGzpTjTCM1qMtH7uWuQU2hF/9M9yBX511Q3ovKOFGeS8D21/hWCljyk/GkdfzpxtaxVLWeqmcIWKea@SQ2cdNH26F1A02qsNoNOh5AWWszF5MAj@/fq9hej9sNjtHkaIS/fc1Pfc4nvnnwXpOJSHi3wcaGSXSid@RKXu1XpuJg71VZZsfLi0Ug3PFJJ4rJr95UNvVG/3o4Lr0dDKVwZfXiZ@JCzvvw0Y/Tly6NEnYjBo@/H8l3z95Ie@QjLRNnXyfbxN6UHKGDjWW1rMsGlXq/deZXSqcj1F7BZmqiplFTnFJPKTKqy9sHU4oQ0OJzz87RdL8dQFotG4vCcSa@/fJ32tJLxKjuJhngxTk2sGXPEohK3uciEu2GHRWqHPz@yQDBMMJoyM3fdVB7rymMLLEo9Ms2KF@TUBKeuTU7xMvwiv@IfM9mTyJlymdkf5wTzG@m8eDcnCcRC91F6NpmS0gTuIvJSd@qeVSRuezwJcbaQ2LVOgaM2A/HBbuEY/FEkJ2xBYSTFFN2jL5rScYGiYd@7hhAfb1N/yz9JvfFJxx50ghtVwTbDZy@sVMLBfRSEoxCxrzgsT3g5GHRw68gK3zW7UOuQ/0vLuG6JIVoru5eqwbJHyrt40g7pVMlTe4B8DQOR@EN4eX4OZzJ4wPavIVpx4tIeealKbywHGjRnni6Jm3mgEHyDBXCnfW4jISMnsweUDgd@I/BSpKOFpP2kpKuttk7Myufp8BtBiDVa0kqp1D9dthufN9/gPvd5sfC0aJHsSl8HF7ynz2IHKyKS@bCEKInLxWeplHU33JC74RwAumoHC/0H4s3gKuj1glSFVgwuGJLSGgbDq6DppVL7QXQJDLhgZdxMwg@7fzlsyOEOKV0@MSO8hENXrsOIw/AX67NcFzf4rsxN4dIqvm2mob5qN0FA43HS6uN2mC8sECZA6IFK3WBERHniqCRKfPescWHdpYuDKKIG4pxYdxMRGXr9UbtBI8MnWakOgZJrkLixXnMCE2qv0fHhHOzNQgDuMTEFDALmKuk@HFL60vy7cFC6Y@aO3Tcjkyfp1@e5QtM9GLZJ@sYE5lHhahbuNMCHb2sH6mBv@/BjZb@q6Pn9/t6H2lZ1S2184jtuXJRztGH1dm@HpEt0my635nv0Il05oJpp/pCq7H5S1R/f71cPDtTevqq9e79TI2gEfr@ye1irHriqtru5c7TFt@8EQe3uHaqd2rvaIRU73HO5VVMtFddTe9vqXXV/8y39rGzUdmqHn7jF7drhLhrDrX5Fva/sH9Y2j3Yq@@r90f77vYOqQsdSW7WDzZ1K7V11y6P2qU1V/VDdPVQHbys7OxMd3fu4W91XbCRg9XKjSlhWNmgLi5a4n1u1/ermIToUP20S8QjBHVcdvK9u1vBQ/bFK3ansf3I10IPqPx1RIfqotirvKm@oc6nsN6hC47J5tF9FBCVQ4uBo4@Cwdnh0WFVv9va2mNYH1f0Ptc3qwZpK7ewdMMGODqquQtpIbppgELXoOz1vHB3UmG613UNaM47ew97BoUH@SIQhLCtUdYsJDDMI9JaItLf/CVBBBx4AV318W6X3@6ApU6sCKsCiYvPQLkYNEhEP7W6q3eqbndqb6u5mFZ/3AOZj7aDq0IDVDlCgBoOMT8Q61OgR9xrjRHjJIzFrynCuy8OpatuqsvWhBsx1aeKAg5rmFibb5ltNcw/xiK1DlHYfZwZ@1z5YaU2/ugoQgXP6RGb2GU0UMWlzb6tKK7IOdpWOPxzRqrM6EUrJ/kYrTfSRfiZC1jSDs8vzervX6sPHNKomBx/d8NxFMiQHmWROUvfkBNPnK1whk6nXP1TqtNE9qNcd9yE1E2h8q4Y@Br@vlKP7iEwT2Hnj4KdUErq/TBBq/Qd90cmGeriAQEmh/g9i@uZ3A0fl881AV4PzPgCbo6NQrk0ucJVCopGdHZECJ26STyb4d1uzA1fMGvBeo45zUlhGcqF@SP/0vsY/ZHGwXpB0luOufB6bWEaj/VtgmpFGOCQC/6MjErRb3KQXBsHn82zBbg57fu@8329mHcfU4bIj2geeZ51vVD8Lzieq5ybrM7J87ayTNIRm380qTHT/rEmm9Lh4Q@5ZFv/UR/zHMdhIzAecmnJTfFitDy2zP0h1WCS5Soe2gHsFDzJ0vneVH2sfsZsrLD1bm3j/Nnovcwv2gojVSwveMdc75T9vT6UATTCOxUEkaesIGfm8VcfYm0SFr6ngBQpdt5uw/KG1@iLgdZ1IQorspd@x28RqPGzf2NiTHH6zX3m3cbS9TaIT2D5bXX6@spaKwm796MrfT2iHw@ly1LEBreOkp/Ena5ZskuLDM8WKZh6zPzNwPo@CiFJvBo1fIs5DZLeRtGSCIEN3Q@SD6sFELx2ADmnFATgepQy/zpyZmgGyia466E3Xv2EV3yddiXlAG7N0xjxqN/gHsKPpb6Z41CHNQJrFOMAwcS7tLljupbeNqShvbjhwD4p4acPHEsYtogEfdbH9LLxr@ZfmbWsUQzFlxHzlYeeahMSjSSyUsavoycx@z3FG9AEwRw@jNz9qfqPHTzrAHYe788NRZXRAZNyOauKcOj6M1p0@1pBPkTUEQdVMSy8VTvkdjRTPPX2cHAUGsWYDo4IUOLDxTQJei@KITDbJFrCvFxz1RTgVwTsAZ01zrP5NnDurOxrKmokfon@bqBRKYEVBToRq11EbKVPkUxTHwpAzQaY/RQ@G/w@kyQz4L2nHSdBjallBAB9ESYYqtKLtKxOlfW0uGqzbjZia9qtPMZhbe2Auoo7p25sb8a8hEujRGZsXnzjsYSs7gwBgchxs2PM3Mkm78Gnr9Drt6Oq4J@k1uoOs0muFWSqm4OZWTl1Wu1xzt4IfjnLkrMlqcIeqqteycTvjWU9bpomtvHocpgWcY@J/5J/wAUg04ZlLL8RqdZKzCnqWGTmgQy1ZC04ziphEauntnbd2T5QVIjMh@/XNlyEUgV4HPtP95PQpfSXmucmIi7wSq0OOgoeg6dgmY/HRIevO2BCzEwDO4yYfhiDDyugaC0RHoHOovhiayj5mQxE0ElsdxnEGIW4dj0jLy@p1hD2fTIJDI@yPehKvP5BTLVPCkwAfGkPbXd5T7/wxodx5WLeFxfJPDvoubBfRmBxL6PrIJtPo94ekOvroN@HotseOpz7qQ4egF14OdfxCWs/aQ30iYZR@agZqk@zeeZmRQPmMWtgewVuh6TF/cJe6ASxEJTzJTW5FZYl5DY@um0PH9s1iUWVfxl9eEk04LCkT8aVaUV@/SikhqA4ZGjAF22G0uWCbTW4H9w7R9LvuDz9j7YcK1GsGzSgyqQWSzwJlkGo9jvHYGEnXB/2QTzRoKHACElGiKAdpkaEqrdHPNTtpu6Z0HB0TsUu5J9/fTsSkxlqKGooZV7dOzLeSo8EElZZ0aNAoWGhxaZlRmbXhur1zM8bRQpPX1ip90otESkmUiPJjozriSeRm9PQJT/qQv/w4xOyhN7jj1iooEIbOinvVaTnH@MGm4GM7GDbtM1HSZJr@AMdvvPXp95gXzdGhDvvX8EdhMKYdQCPfvskzjHr2L/2LXn2z3/HP2/22T/s0RLm/EYmHxzE/YsDOh/3rkBMl8YemVag5jp8lvoyEYcPv6F5yzQrNFY6CQdY2UxgNx5ULCRPBJ@cwAoyTtDJ/DyZjpEV1ni3HlVJJ/1O2xys6a3fWfVqcVVlu9AFAC7j1CQsK8SEdsWOS5Xy6NlXg7L4CFo5nKqd85w6LvQTGL4hEfA2TwNggM2WWYHcCO7M7MT5u3rhNjkE4RKClYCtA2p8wy69dH3mvSYq8gqVASRVXC1ZVuUW5QRxCPIzvJvfS838w9oTAn0C/@HQWt8xiBBZxLRNtKZT9io4ySriweWCbZTRLYpJi7fN2z3I/5BwbN5NQk5/Hd1GDLX9IKdJh9qa4EjMySxsf5PPL1knk1McOFpUFteBw3A6oIJVRtnA3wwbfsp/lyY9LXDk5g2Da1JCzFtJ3kapBVEJm4QnzWhtlian87RmztPTQUZsgYHmWyZmV4TqbNpoLe6C0ZX3FtVZ/SMI4PUE9beqxEI76g4UHUu9O2TEzMtssWjcc55uGwMJsZVosnzSZtOUxHsdrqUl8JpgmSTG2NCMewvaVnyM2nyTiTbmO@Vauj79Bh7toFttNRYtKNN5NmftYFK9g0WsWmmhKMe4IUroWvT@uU8frd0sQDVO2V3WWGHWIjPpYHi1QE2SKqPRwCjH3adwn6NEkyqHdJtHOHp87iTppJGdCnppPiSCXoCcCt8Npk@TSoAXjC4SJEw03ElKRwnnjjvkqr5g7Q5BhfBCA0IqDXHwOJSe48WBN8BFnB2hl67AWKkIS0dO6beEQBf2PCMZR@fXhjrZ4qI9zxdM1gXQTQaJdBZe6D5LxN6efx/UbhjJFCpriM0gR9WhKNl08vFd/ti9UjiBIbf6sLX0LLjrjqEXChv6xP9VvoAPHTemaiRmVnAh1Fg00F2iXct4JZLsK7a89FI6HdYOeRrSBkNdZ/FnUNRDOe6UQURtVbppjFHE0uWW2OSq3LlVihpLfIL@eiqLq8saVAASCMdUvFwkCwpoy9rgU4NA7NuclENVjRBXLRUxLeslRUWM7zxnfQVRd4NmyVaIwq8QLG0ZuJhBSLGaXiREhnWV2kRgKLXQzcbFKPJ/dn7gEKcSG94XiNBR6VJI0jEZOCMgptQtOLFGOi8otaA7mj8@WncTHiL/564uC9bUw@ZXoE2F4nCtOfl0tJL4mml1aSlZN1CR6OHariY9ECsdGOJIKf@5/7JpihzyPbEKtTUZCy9D22Uh5TrtM2rd5v4TqJTtlGx3DwLM9w832qy4pVhJB2e8PwK4W@MoAsdv/dG@NZarBROcK4Lh0xtklKxtC1ljTWOrRLex0TaS9KECB2dP2W@rD4fZ2Iuzr2dgYGnWD4XKhUAATn9nB741tNY6S2v18snS@ddnp5AfXfxl@OMuz7A8CTglQMjvogIaEJkXo9YfnkhkCOFBRlM5pR1bs9S9bLTsFA24oMXg0bFJSR0NQvAC1I6OXD4d8AMQg9QL7MzqI/v2sotl37YuiqaGYayiqDZPgq7S5PSPy4EUL9tnRTRUDg2A21ky0bjnl9S9YQZDZhAeLwxc7X2Lz5PTboNPpu@ojUi0jUsDc7WSF7W27QkGK4IaRvXsvQ45H66rgqt2x/IpRxOZ1gDMLk8kzYeLCIzb@fnBevRlk08c/pWlZoS4vopuLiE/tqvR52tHB4h8AVviQ0H5Q6a4/yDaYTpOFaanXMzh@IoyeFt2Ze59EEYfPxDTNvl0aRJ2NrsfBGqjrDusCJpY9Dy/35I7iEXHTJzfFFmhYEBgaJ8RceVgNuJr948Ti1ajVephU5DQAMrDfJRElE8qfE4h8B8AzUE8/oieiaP81R9N6eyKgiCg4SNYxLXdQoY4KqdTjRvnX62ylUlHzg8VFVals0EMupyobFbWFFxsbaot@b@D3D@Wl5eU1kblbzhd6uWFe3qoNgsEnnIuNi@EW/aRvZfiNwVobQzyfL8@7a/P18sv1tTB/XNmAWz89/ee//M///Nf/la/oH/@OHxv84/inqJDnefn5xpf5H27X8Pt463Rh/ux4fnC6cL4GLvsbRw3v10Y5PzYf9YZnqYysAtZbtiM1@2yOPqOrKpMlsOsPP5N0KalMI8xn9NtQMkexjM00Aut9AD/KM9rCm6QDk1t5QiJDQMc4jqfRaQQwwKP1hihJuMAOVOrL3Yo5uEc4mKhAdKuS0ZF4WGe9CuDTEkdSgC8urVi5di8MejgBv2KdV7qXSvn0tz2qa/7N//QuPN/o36gnJ1n1pKCeuOpJOs1/iisv6K0zn2/DO1eK0XYgnXbpS3y1ADNDFbZZ0eP9A@famSB3KjXPKXsAyYSp4MLiBedGuz92lpGEa@F5ag6ZRpUckfAlE6pkvsz3bmlYvlCJ23TC1YYVhbrexXBj1o1KNL5QgfxQDAHilrtCkFKfmsRNH3sk4ylv3uixTnE2IQYMsu6/2eZ5jxe0Fs33tM1zYi@FNEdsPi9vsTauiTM0o40v0n6MAF@oyHaywJ6EC5mFlFh5W73kbooXtt0/zXxi6zAORsY2XSr9riwmEGtum3DzPe3Xog255XpFpdvR9YrVVHrS9lulrCrdy86oPdDuCtw6JtSXqLVbmUkYUQYkcCRmf2l6hvFBgYkUNTEskixrrJp9dF1mQk@7ptMAO57cHFlEyP@Upbn9dWJuO3n2EjHsIDzASEWmfC2/3Ql11JUhE/vcH54hO6Df4oRqI7k34/M8ZIydwLjfipD2GDKbnMfzmbqSGQz9867vqsxu/3Doj2u0bJHmM2p4DvUQIZiABCafbnpW9wzC0iM9JEyRqCtsOYTkBZ2xTo8mY5uOfE4wpGYq6LArmAQJdmJKBl8TYzVBx5irv2MQbJSnhHd0G6lFLEteWBppSGnbbYan2dTUSZkW7LkTTZx0SlCNZqbhBV3pEgttly9@SZJ3ECNAt53WXoDaFWHlBdrH6nQe9PzE4jTopIyjf35NybqI@cypKMUaKaWhPC/GGe@AFemRPyWjQMjaZMIZpeay2bmTUKdzy9jrCAf5jmzx875qRwnoOIEZe4aoo15bhOXEChXnwPBUjS3/CUKr458TfuNrfwxWPMlkXz3KO8c/nfROn2RPel9PfnMYEy2SzSqbUxl9mW0klp4rtDLm3cRPY5UWmlCDJ71kgZOeEh8WiwSESD57/FP@9GueEDrJOM6T/ElGCJIYMmCSv7@9PMDnp9DMJLHIZ1JzzhPHDH72VdFRtLbyX4yhvHDkL2FhNpV8TE/7nGGLQLGf7q@X4nIS5leXCs@Wis9oJ3Qe3OSGwSXW21x4eRbckCoRYjtLS8/JbwluSBDi9ib01@jlDfVT0pqI70monZS0CNXTnNtJRWxFdTzhCSpPVOZwqXBxcaIyPi4fseF3FbGcKcuxoMR00OK@LNbPsN9FO34IuTbpHSIcCSsDsRHhI9QcIJvkK3dxqGOmywL7OXlqE7FbGQgNbz5jrRa9fi@nlTXHW1iDEg2vmc5qYbUwOUenpmhihs5rZWrhkSquv3r@H/@292tmlFlfyn8c0t9R5tfMympGHumBfj01v64y65mXKLZymxnnaQ9Mj8//439T/fW/EBx8Gb@kf9aXDayVcWY9V@YqXzPrK/RQXFqidv/PP/8z9WFedmzIxTpfdxUjtmYosun3mHfpu6qhl7ItXYjFCjtmAYZYGNLenH7AMOpmabXAx3QZbVVxFejIV8YeRS/xbJg1YlMhOckw9hSkGUmFMhrICUhjQtFSlu2GMdsA88Zoqp8feysh7QB@1uYcUZOR6cbjECZD87ItogHMSou0n5eH9cKrdGTeUUobm5I1o0Jia6dl7erTNWKH9/1g1G4krSTMdO02/OvgzAMfekHzkvZUvbDT/2WYvyKW7BaXVvMtHO7n2Y47P2BIucHY@40UQZ0MiDaGbHTqqiGNQL@LEF4uZwsihX47upMy@SRJyx4EDTnDSuYkpiLi4@fK9TC648WqdJb/JQUemTN1IkgrV9pJj2ru7ZdUejEqKOV4z@sAm/dsHKtDYOTEGnbAsslLcR9wOmj641WG5@yExLUQdV2KeH6zWff1t2xqLm1SpbmpuYugMyinWxLeHbFTcWOi6S9q5p1Qcm2cIORyLOgAqxuMfNqil9P8BvvxuAWESdF3rVGouJisLV1W7@qbZc66ck/T19L0NY0otIS4nYhnrGhsyi4msqWMo8phUMeV2syGqbXQJG0eevwHGIQyLLUW3BJ0d9gDkqgWd0dbldnD5vJemHjkOhCfPTlalMzVqUzs/OiaEuJBDd0J7XrSGAkIRMEtwUKZfh@IB0TZpBlt91ISz2/is4nvocFwH/YQStQOWyfBR2VZ6l0h9017xL6Uikig48raNtgpWT0i0FGIrSgFbRoHL2kHLNUq8WaLC5rhKHEaaBMSKp2Wc6rjhorSy7Z09lpJFEEv0oXi0tNnyyvPV18gy9mc7u1sMKjkYRcwuPAJBmvUWdpk4325nF5IyyukoJ5uEtBngcUFHMy6rh3HhH2@dh6ViwUNrJBmWNecRkOq6@NKBhlDHAYeVgTao2SH6Wz2VekYHTs9aTpf6T/ibxMfkBnOhKP1hfTWOLyPI1OluhJwoMyCmYPiZJ8igoqjv9hlg35rH9EmAti6CttTQzuIADG6GPYvzy9s7vB0aKtDmjBEcI5LjR3Um2AUBxizsIIuqg8capb3RdnAO57uAYxysSRA5xPgNM103EpfW5pidizQIoTImvBYxRWiZTpqszNzZ6@vqrtbk4hl7DR0DNezLVtJueNIZgggg1y9VncPibo62gW7kmqZ5CaiKrOAK6Bckd3hffhKN5CI2qKKkdWsN4yy95GlyLwYhzaNq9I4Aq8ZMIuFb5PS@LWaXoAgRhDq06RIiLnRfY5Nshgne5AxT8HL6ZJlI/quHYYcYE43lna0RSkX4qwCc6k7AOLcppCWjhRKGFF@rHLiZRltJHMUr2gcDWgz5GinGswsyWkm2Oo2lADYyDpuaIH@13Y3XbVVpX@2P265UJQ3Kn9Fv6MUz3fjW9T4Fkuqtm2GwI4Wyza3sJn6FS5KxCwFHTA2RhDCtyVZEYM4akC1tq1pL5P6ODG3T2OuALv6Wgk3p6N6kiDQC5@BzOnNexSKg911@F1JDq@mJU0UUkVPCzniun9iWzSZi1uNIAkpHwBiaRJEFKgl5va5mOHFAp01b1/vXQxj17Zn83SCZWVDRWr7dp7InuTZOylzH1ssabZYKmEc7@ML5tt7eeMsaPW1L1rEHN/gjUd/jDdyD2eO3H8L5qj@Y7jjqeaOpyXIHuGOKGw4e3RyGvb@DI45G/MaXG@2z9s4H2pZP9GJgmsBYIEHDOFDSh@LBfTtDnGisrM/LE6uRzASWlqGY8Af6vwz3flnJchcftwK/qt2Pvd37vyy7vxyCWvNjJHXqp0Vbv3v0@NYJcwmX8wcXqi7Usz5oz1d0T1dKWE1nTHM/997mvt/1NPnuqfPS4iYIBcOEr7@fm4WTaRysFmrxeYWXkoH7coij/1srnSw92qW07R5aHUuw4sytHX1h/Ff1fivQhrxE9LQ4S4isg2N9vKyPRVnedEs@ZRDwclKeiL9NZHRrf7qBSvej@gFSoQ0H2wN9UaFFHJXPsa3TV6sP8bSN1p8HoqzyHadLBMX59YGWnaERSee4qL56iSZSyvRurLFMZDV5uH@zuL/EDJ0/c/aC42Qx9BeB52OWUnsLdhhFHVKd8bqDmAf6D1HglU0ORnZkfb2jthl7m6pxoEtJtbF2ZsEuWrD/R/tpbrQN6ys3DgyItp4ur7ZVcE012wv5A31XQrN7rLu8R/i0heaS1@U1L7eGNxFKl8f@GlejPdpS8vL960BUsvDH0zAgkvl75lV/xc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/r8b3y)

I installed from git repo on Ubuntu 20.04 with ghc 8.6.5. To fix cabal errors I changed `^>=` to `>=` for `mwc-random` and `random`
in `Fungi.cabal`.

In Fungi `0k;12` skips single `;` *and* `1`, and executes `2`. In the polyglot it ends up executing string contents of JSFunge-98 code:

```
>0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;
```

Last `'` is for fish.

Answer (score 4):

## 377. Befunge-98 ([Eso](https://github.com/Dash-Lambda/Eso)), 16386 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#8""C""Hata>;re^;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?MLot ~5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_9   $x/
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,@9
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9    >"473",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @763",,,@;z"482",,,@_   ^_^# +1y2^;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdtVVdUl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYk8daz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBldn/OdnXTy2tZQcBYe@5gOjLsiVcRYkxlzNLtwVQfGKxvWhPDTTPPMFjHsJxzCNcY257aU8/o1eEty5htnLNDu2v2AAKbOKeGbb4xXAjLMfbAsC5HlxPWdUYj3e55bOya9oRC84w91eGlP@2eMr3jTVy9OzEdG4IKjD23LX3U6emMoo9dgycqMgDVPaU0yyElxp44rmdADk7X8DwHPcvgqbum83jv04@vxVcz7GMdkBpbxuxa9qrKPjcNt3c9hcY@O3n48Lpvln1Ncmz28CZKao7tTSfO4eQ6/DzbGxi2zjS5LGvXAwtAzIlhlTKlzPWgItSnMTG7S/lAwEPThdrV/VpkXd2G2sK63GLGaDyZM4nXv25ZYd16TPfY1JvqFsWzp6OO4QYRvYnuTkx7wM7NyZBNhqYXpqPY3ljvGlLPsMyROTF6zDIhkdP3oQBou8dOjfm540KV@zAd25pDQqNr9k1MEuABAPFKTIYGhzPS51DJ9gQaB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/gOjMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPh4btN2YAJwOIE4dj9WpKqBmLNq/3eiwD7RjwODWYCVQjtCosmwV/5rhANYgVYOQDo3bNy2jMoM6givpOheUzGQg/CH0QW93yHB@ZZdQw0Ia@SnWGcJ@6zsDVR0CNnkE0/ezwKfO6jgtv8MO4vD/dBqarT9j2NosffPogzuphtchuRwirqMYuoApiQSA7060ptJBoTThQP26YWsAqi2/EKywOZNEyLJdjOei2JablgUhqpgwO6P9aVoVfgWklllOhB@Xjacyn7@oD0zI4lAFCKWLD1/JMg3smx7JqicccOFafR@tSZkWWLbFCkRXzrAj3MitrkBuCzjG1nIdfAX4ArQyoqPDL5jigRbuHdoptbZ/19ZFpzX3oBL7L8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW8hWFPRkCtYf6GYCXLPMUuZERMiSsQgUeytaWQhwRWS7P3hti9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaCbLPZ3hBvKFhWX6yoYfJCNtiBn6AeRHoUALqZ4CWGSRmEX7wDvxOA8amARfTgDFpwEw0DdxZzALiFSCsAFVZ8Ok11L1TyIjno/WI@MDRAYyK1EYmpiKRAALUFstCnRVYDhpCFhtCPssAf8ClWGDAx0oqK@VYqciAnuUMg7pRAS9sJSrwTxXwUREY1L8KDUAFnFSgtgpA1WyeCRFiq1kMh7RZSAukUXOQJgduqDi1gD9IBy1DhSxVyFPTyotGCLhpeShvPkutUytA7RYhDOimAa4aNCcNsNVKEI5pS0DDEjbeYjzNCaEjHaBWsLlDOwRi5AEfggtxwa0Vs5x@ujUe6h3k1jxlp49JC9gNCkhGSJrB4sEzh9QEVDIABnsBoK9BC8gCObJQtdlcmL2lApAGgjd6JjFoywTepYYUKqapQb7Sx5MF2dQCYTSeT4ahn8b9HGCcJjA/Y6B352Eg9L50GLjwLWTRVyNeuwCUyaGvB5zVmXrWAkjoyGmUlXFmWgu/Evn1DL3XN73h2wWuOcqkY@gT2zxd5JLPpyNE1SMBBQxY8ipmo3EnpgTD1WCIrkVZtCLGGTthBS2hrKqEXsfoT@2BIZVLEfwoZDJ1JzCwLPIsc2/XHAxgTF7AUdNUTBooF955wtDKZidC6InUxTxdE4bve6w7BIEiDCxz@OXyAkZWQxhzvYOjugRSGIwCZRy3@uaMde51adRYIJglOnWH5jiIXFkbOVK5lMmsVIi0DaLcm1ImZM14teRXjmkn4iyeFK4EGGu4ZBkdqWFA@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@t9Y4yHAIKNeqw770L3hErG1iP0HGIw3fFyMRdvmwbEsVEp2X/682xgANlBYO2jdopNflGA8ZiKQKTQbS7M2jpQCovQHc@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@@uZy9ii96cdc3ZdC@@ip/zKE850l/VRAXdB6IBOlIj3vXiySv6UMhIkKs54olBSfhchIkWSocoTfdDpYZB4CIzmeG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ5MyGU09gmoCtexQ/UBG83oFPo1vVXZAIZvSYK7hH6ECQYoMgboLsgZ0AlByyyXex2dXQL3cJk02@eqSKCSqHIuzMuwe2FePiEQl2h5ZZ6F53bJIUVGNSwBRqeS0yCxRMD3pAQlFMFDUfyxFT1I2uNhJNdwz6lN83AswUWRJLsIhV8YABKEjAnCh9k1J21fXLl3LxBcNmo1aGwgTQHb7CWjGm0wYSkDp4bIMkkjfibyxDmeYN9IJKG8GPmKYwNiE7TUWp1dTIYu9Dh6vxIgEpBVsLElB4T16/lT83Tau17RNnpiJBF7HQhNZnciVgUY/HlvqN1G1fgSVUHrjSNVsfFiegJ9o/GSL1ao6EdzDQ/F35qPSqSGE4iB31ZXkogn9f0WDXp/3rV8kYC7oLNzbtQB9E/9iayQEaV9mSDotDd6KgeC3YHDYU/3Th7V/L7IA5WOaVeWPCynq1vkvYnRxSDt48P7z/ae/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@EH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8@jZ166TBCQhJAflAG78XRNpeBwQuoSO7g2vDcJskEpBlmGSIC6TDlkAM3Qg6hiuB/g8nb55g5V3Hamx74@YWVOdAwg8lUM7SCdj4DUBLAjq9PmISGlBCjVtXGhYuKIxA3w@Rqn5OjIkSkeazMdHDw@e1QisP68mURTFm4Aspbs9Gdq8NQUVfFUcYH/g6rKUvEAc5WnCdSWBu90lAi/qlq2BDwBQ15EdJlmjoGjeEHDfv1428pW6YQugd4JwXa6MykPdD0U0ggcOcV1UeVeNohSwGKxCr5UjVhi6PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs9eFCgtCsA4EMiNLgSdehL6yAsp0herffSPH99A3CMhElQBKcDMs5hMeXmWgNqLZLK4p@yDhuZYhvw5cTyRiUlFiQfrAnLXI@UzEv9gZk4SmSR/qkmIC7nv7R1qD4LI/pQ1zWSQ0oC6OI5Mbh/X97oetBHbsZyBw7YgDZcOgwxBbFpbzL2BY9@oIR09sagxXCIE/osTN/oYxhrzDSmOlCqqrvLFRt32zoFLq4UsEokoRKAUii@/0s90INei3MeH3ziAQUTNZzKhO0MXkCCShsiFrm7ElzyYBBnJPj4rCxguF97o7UGAFFmvw0L7jC5MuLcIXulJHFNWVsZfidInzg2Kv3Lm15oW@PCmBY4IyQ4/ffr48NODJ3tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC0A4yK8DspA85HTD3rrFuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyR2BNq@ELrYlPnKEd95LXC3OOodIru8ub0BPsfDyqnxAU7Z6FyojLV6txPMf2M5xMxl5FUaCXD6cdGZRW5VXXsfSBQulgYLAsRUXV5fAI5zW8VSkAGW9u8BR8cgtEhznNIOrWyAHlhda8kTWwBAdPs1aWORiCLowL44ablMMWTKVReqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1WtxNu1mtFyihhEW@r@EHejb4DqlIDRCkiRvPbKmvea99gcuDRCug4kxuQtmuTwGI4FFgNBkmZNUc8PiEPcAudLkVcQjV5PcTYXuJSSz@SKaiGvgFoGahrIrBLOuUkjfdIdShNHAniS06d5g0gr7Htd3e7LW74jQBbkvo@gqNnGi2bTboGA3rxHuOG6c2PeaqitZJXdTLLlx09WofUuFQ/bbuABbZec0DTpydbws55@k531dOpdPaZMRmN/zJHG7MkeCFJvHODXPSPa9zCBEg1UtpbiKhj5rbJiQsjCpALekFIKdCgYaaHpKYiXBEIviofQcoBvRRKwxWwGLwff3xHhI6h0Y7s3nbhHayQo1@BsqTcGItJkcxe5tIfzgxMYHcOWj1waKheZNDs34jiPrnt8thIS@Wv8QXrQ1UIINCsfzkjb4a4GaASUitRz4BzQrnDadLiYZUSlH1oaZEg44eQDSBA2rR4MgM9AYl6QPV4QnhP5LBfp1HbObYTWMVhJ6pgTPtnvTF1c6zZ70bJB9KzG4wA0KlyEr9OieMfo8llWnphKAUqgzkbGyMGpBJCuiBUYVASdL6ijLujhjDV0q4yEK4YAX2K7@8DFugafL5JGqERBkzpg8Ymr7EnfUHTpDbTmW2QrLHykiv1KPwkIsLy9gWZJ/BlQkk6cEUX6nOZbMPB@IO4KuGIIJYYWJuo1Z2zY13U@rhEmklXahhCP80Wgi/jGxka8Eq/H0@DaAdc2unbQlQLXDrkkcmE8GV2UIk0uDG1QCvRrxa8aAeRZsoVtYIaSwxtznNAblUq2ldYbqv/U8JmEqgDKQ2wJHwAnnqzV0JlMivVzXLMB@T1S9n1sO8dd1xz7JPgEBAL@7tMgS0QA9R6ledeoom56O0VGNReURgNFzIQbbzYyzVbzotlLNa/iaUydrOo10A@BeU0SI3ngOtMxCG6NXEUC3pZsZCutaqcWz8S3EomSZEFGejL5USmZ0jmtE3ED2lSi2YwDSX3qNLpDl@DN0loyGRIK8OiboGVYViIuX5Qg/06ylUzFIW0ynga2XIvHgS604OhRoXFGgDeih@YMSAkdE4a46JoCMUhanMLu@g1jPJy70QjhrBtI2TiDvtirglt6kItHueQbnj4q0C1p@oHcy@OBcIuTdygvjeecuwsc06aytDMqGHfPpP7ImejKZzIoTXJkuIxvxBVJgpGQQjgkKvYT08MurNuGM/WiM40rJ0Axd/A9GU6BWQbb09LQqsyxYHSHDotv7gJ0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16UOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8aDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSR5ZvQEC/hHH9ijzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hBECSoOcWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEjjgRgO5dgdC5znraZpW6Ob7lSAMWwUQewiVhFqpDSpuECSpEJj0K/mATwsFOvqnRw8O@NwJDbY4vOI8Wnvk9KYgV/p60zPDHqTZAbQn03ZGJpAhSP/m1HrmOBOu5cPLupkZrjSbo6ml05zP9WmZW9N1nY5j0VTQbUkX8aeup1s6n4QKQvc@ewKy/vOT45pciURS9LPRrXnjPOTqbDk9D6NrjrTeGiwPebxhipt5EcetYNcnshk/oIABU3/PJ9RR4F9E/6BL4RqK719C/xHu9wRZ2Z9FoNfQ049Ypoi4BxQ3vPmeF2rmCv3X6mBhPJXiccFxge2FqpH/2aTfX/LOkvephKzJWnjnyJvvBV3SEaMo5Xkk3Bi6FCcKqEBxwv2ha@MVKR7f3SKHK4tPwk0IQ8MKlhafgcSCy2cw6FsoV4HSgiI638NpgIQ9xlUSYt249sa6IIR6N@YzoLONJR5biG1QB4LBTUGRRthUmD/3XaUuZDv@mqXH2aoDOj9Nq2zX@So36lQuV@cUPiu/2QYQ2/VqsOFuXTTMKR4PoxFUwg1SUDFpYf9GUcNtGh5NtguUpCp4CqgTMy0jNWfFg9ZlXPGIDH0mNpuzjzLaF6CX4G7JzXvKwKjSHqc19KoGIXFfhu3MmQQSH8biE9fdIfAZlpotkxLqZ2r3Hasn8VUyaDCM61dYQf4mhXAXp79Z1zDdYAMn7aDlSZG/RvZ@3oB7rUrrNyNEdouGgKD7XLDL0/TZJWvAkHcme2PLnLTYlTxx2kN/p5R9fV8pl0FdV597gr/Hpcb2nn38WSPT4hCEkY4rXyVei7NgezIIziAo4T5ycOFOnYk5IUmAdiKYWF5VBqRmtEgC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULUL43LRVn6BmiqCQMx9@ajNDOSV3Lf0icTw@Ztji8/ric3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8MAxSo7Pnlw8OyZDC3XS8QPcAWnAt1R7w5BQFlX6ICS0cJX2Ee9OPsI0yRRbRegq4H20fbTQ6OuQqMH/QNyR94xMNwEeCZx8aUL3rTeRQm5hOYTCPdbdSdEoxBYwkhCmQhYZSX@z22uavl4VqDFp4iSQO7EvQrQ1kzKU9t8LXsw0JDcClHiXFmF8aK2mSAutqkm/Q11I1w6Bg2LhEYoQaPBpDfA5SCyyFqtKt8DAHFRAXMHSF1RpKqgXew1Naj6GniDSEMQ/OS1t@xFIyOVW6nNVaBoc5m/AZ2XPwIXISyD9oyV2W4mqL/f6MgcB74WyDn3c1Knr52@qLBN7hD5nDNFDzZMEdOh/VXL@6SWd2FBJ0NWQlMxWJCAJcT84wF@m6Vw4vyg82Ay8kgk2UVIdA1Jzi4viYZsU2NEQ3CpjFfGVaB9AmN67EBpHvtHA6LSAfVWfyMJ9tmmIAZq1vJKLYZwEV45uyadSmdiNB2XDk371KH1ntDVzshqHiXCMPXo1LqZEjeh0m0paogDj6utw84bdfp0WxGBlj38BXXyoAl1XxYGIVJXntGD5tZX5Ly8iWQpW397Ko204GbS6ztiSuUSRe53Oua6qEAE3BcWPFdEAyaF7VmTc7IanDXAqRgYj4Bxce1lUfTr@4/YEt39fbT@8z9/swf0v1k7QxgocOYxdLRh6MaakvprK8tPii90W12xfIJ8apk6EYZcd4Hs6i4USbdCx2rQtAgvSTD8j3BJwa9xaJt4A6nxlmbGMecrgsFzdSarFtVsYJnddXGv7cfiWdHyDyh2PSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYMz4EkxExUY2djdSwaYpRo2Z1/twOpnyOwiud1aiOcbfbX3Tj5nJ6x3VUPjO9Vuq3NVPpz1HGp8OQjm1sCLuovS0BiyBOOAvB7fRubr4vIB8J3jwXBdtMbQp5/S4q1V49tQbSx3Swnv8jTrC6JYcXIvf10Ux/cN7oWM91UyLbu/ZEn3o0FD83RAK7jWVIkQzr5HZ0jtzlEGGH97Kwp0FwHFq3VQqk12ztDwer0@PmiSlL5dXp57JXU6PVXMECt/PKvFZNCqwv8P1jlqF4coc6Zak9SLOtcx81caEG1HDNU1Kg4cv6ATGrY0cB6Tu1NLdheuWJr7AI1hGWDcj7Q8bT82uA@LAmKlFWdWCoSMyYBDLDLbGLTLC7cR0i2x/MFeRMThOIoWu1SzA6U5wy@iaNvUeDI1v1cQNsZFGIjvrKNV1zvG3VnwYgmrK76tHtDcrsXoP5iRZXUuHcXztcLA0OYiTj3c01HPTM@i2mrCnKxGddK2V/stdIJj2i07j3dWsPdNyPHZM99sINHCBCvy@ukFHaWnqtkST4VH3LTwo2OOwqFDdGjhWoTRQdLitrfWp20e@7z/fl8OFHEpV7@BQgfjj2Kr/XMvXTxX39K4KogOLLu5vjThvGWJXsSl/7WV96UAxwIW71SV7mClRSlnhU31rMsYll3N9Hjx/hqFjHWmDoWM8J3EapDtMUC6BY@JyEftnyS13e26992NKN8AW7ypEpHJPLQMGK7rfqFKmZdQPTKFmMu/PovrW1JgaKxWNo84rA4/V36JkvD9SGb8Ym/5MPS4O4NGUMNYbXzN8L6xxnMa3W5mJbpld425RZpmpjUH6HqPq/BQcT9FxM8XAno6XanVJO7Of3U6y4Tjo0k5vCTsM@VA@VLpDUlqSzz2DfrdqTFzDww1itXwmk/EFmMiKy9LLbZpUNkz7yuT3pYzJZ5HzIi6usrkR5@o8iCzRLYhrWZC2TrGnyOWyYpu2MZnj/T25acdxrA@pKWCqeGDYAW1Voq22t9XYDXHHP0TCFlMXHk54dPrrJi34aOPrlkAfVJpvq/ToktB71aaEi54jXJBafr19@iaywHRXLni4FeeE@OZba70s6c@GqHJJLt7a67iE6nQMS@ePWSF3G7yynL0V3jLT8BdrcXGXL@kuluJj15jSeA7EMnugpQyNkUGvt0j5eg9NZPiPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vMDozuughjE/iCjfelNeSIsDRxbNCvJrjPD/UUC3eS@r7rOHCw6reSyIcjfWBwmy23ccrFhAXupuFq3cK5euqiwnfQdCHZwhjH@iYBnerUmHvBcyXAJ/Mu1Ot0dPd027XO38U50Pfo7eu2sN4cYu2hM7SHxpDvGw/f1nUOaI8TbmPnNtQB68EQt7KNx0tb3KP0tBzLeh96ImvkjNJx@itxOsDDr3hy64Pg8pP2/uPOyTt9wnkHOtb2mqExhXHJcybO2JDobV1UCyd6@H0dDw0WqX/WGaRb9XygSPD8WeHfqVsOdGcyHtOjPbamHt0oqURnlu@Sm/p8awptinTcgfzGGXVk31P2963QEvhqFtMxJ90hHhrnLdsYOJ3u0LwLad9QhRJM@fDX99JdkTImkx6gt2yZQF53LmN7qUXDj/FxuK7S/dkjPqyFjlvklVUzdHQsWxrrp12Pz4aii1VwQjjSG/nh7Qodf6@8npqTBdDIXqZwepcvS6BjHe7@7om1khWdkViwYX9XxdpWSkI6CuSSkQGBR12X7fI@t0gXy2b5bR1C0VISRpF9KR9Cbn/vD80OmpF5W/Bfal9Lm5ZWDnL2cDrwbjJMPl3fAxENb@unLWgvc2TKGsYs3fYf68isWQoecoRnG2SuqXHrmkr@1kUViqdaku6Y8GjDA6puunYOzTLHHr8zqb92Kc7fywS6@PX1Qk6b@Wpl2q@YntHnSyDouktEHDku7kQGGUTq4ko6zqAjM@eCF2dctjMApi5ZbBE5iLtObFm5TWh19YdjpvTFp8ZAx73Wj80JbtZc0Sqoya7aXnQn7K9Pdc/8@hRKtq6xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeE/0gdl9tFQRIZI@gf2dnvyx1PzR62ZdnA9ND3c0hY5bJqawyfFGjK2uDXrDipjX5@1DYxWLDsSPQa6MvWpu3RnP8bTYnFy3TaubE5pl9Z/rVMd1m8BuReJ8OhpPPf@xGgfaMxWdhR6dkr93bgJw6TWwVjbUrcnqmerIlCtIYf6guHCuk8a/YVrOgH2jlGEgtIEQhsL5ioZzH4bnp7ghx7VXtETK@z2XPXGiQ3J5wV5D3RpZJpm2Obl9Nmcywc05wRMLw0cOPKGgPMa7vPuhEKST1RR5fLesvziafMf4Di3v2Jm6XQOdob2RqFrg52rsB7uP8USHg/ZSzqNaWtexoHuBw1rZZbqOPZ1I7tS@dVQo3DoqVNDaVKQZsMTXD548T0ZbA@3WvksKDeyRLVxrNwxca2SmDYLYej66HDvQJR5wO0nPaKvwHWn20JhTl9j1A2eVvvN0DgPIeytMwPynowdGF5cN78z7U@eJYzswGo2BUY6eGfzM/9JGj9UJMdljPNUO9Ondmc0xgV0zCHFpQx8bHahfa@F6n7GIA36gT/Q1QxHNDZL@F7rubCum1THcVzTpF3GvU2mXEXpkzEi3WN9geB@UJt0uF4lxPm6pjyyt2Hhjx7H5nbhtBh7qk9u5CgwFdHv/hXIZN@IvzQus1M@Wi3p0xneJGD1ulGJdWV2j41j8fsueJNvkewJ01zQ85THaOCC/Qo5JIH15t/KQ4q08ZKEagSR7pnu0SL9a1ViAVGcfsAVoqLtdB1fCfMctu3MihgnuYNPh3n6@caADhJ8Bx9K7U99Y6F1oWaPOiG5rFYZIbT4zOngqqEPWPCb67GZl8pkh35RBZEdXaAAgYFfYqQss8RS0keTdw9aSHrVMVXNMN@LUa5fLabOOZJtG942Os2YO0WsxN70UDmVWPiXnmrnqSDeiWWRFp5PuK3vS8tY1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclt09uBmZUV6yHTkYGLzMurMGtFV8cbUmGd1evpIXN1Dcm39Qe8JLT7x@VDaW@t5Ing4f/o/icKDMLtQi4wPQKs6@4VfEB@6tr@431a4FPHm/TN2RHgjacA1rETLFYeksCD9wx0ba0rBNSePbX47MMgsu9q1CN1TCIrzJJkEbueGJJhn0lkCG52s0QOP/Sl7KH13onRk3w7CLjSID0Ozn@F0fznigXUKG/EzZ6qwgk7K@T87Z@riHsecAaQt5yJNPboqYy9p4ePj07ksaeuHJ/2hng64oYct2RYQStlIlNSr3Q3st7Jt6P1TG@i3D9Wpf3HhzJGWENvvqIhwQNX5pYea@c9Ayuuir5WC8JQY7JaQHx08uRxanFEkyX2h64zMpLR4P3j4zSeNPnkeGVwNPVD6B19Z7Y2@eGBqiZXNN/nNq0OruOeK3JaB@nEAG0UGuMjbpflTuGq64yN3sl8bHwGgydycO89sy@sLeSn@pk5wF7IymsJRR2VleVCLhnZmQ3KtuGGz3X1eWqOkVt26aHwx9rtKCg5ZBU3u1p6uG3F/7oUwzL@ToQPS6RmbrbWqB1hRff@voipqrqOzsd6H@qV5ddW1nKEVevDlnP2HkvJhq@8SKGXNIFWJZl37iMvSiNg3QrecHre9wRnZ@02mNsAhN6FlR3@3LDnui3RWtZt4kUFUuOmtlujfMN4jwWpcIfPGRorX7nGF26pZ4kuOZN3ZHziRpLs798/vCvBM5@Wt8f6@NPn7KnuoRGS2yNGMTbeA@OFZPRKwnkrtIC3djm15wIo7VZ4g/Hq/lxhx7rbc@z57O5FODqDikM7GRcOYeEbRTIsc2auGqu6fF7r6eptRnflzQ9xOPMlOThqnMYH9O7b/0xVMxkyPYRPNcNf76iZoIOzBLr0OdqziwadHIasoYtyiwweyZXa6GNjhttR@GzwKqV@5fhWuGXsKybXDye3hZVuCcvdkt@NMPRkWTmj3gIwf0sYy8th8GPHOh868r7uGt6K/ccrEbqtIOVbClKOcGffWjotLPru9SI@Hl3wHytb64kxcXPjodMxcyvLsNdHI5PsCRpLvxnub6fQXdreMnD8Ix/8fXV@51NjZUZP9DerA4jTnK4MAiZoDKd0JOJm8PICaQdkXsMemNy@IrvvTA7o7RbFLDzxvHovgjl@MB2vxxh4I36S4jo7X4r4OejMzrnH7uPRuIWYvkL3x/1xq/3XybQsnBhEM6OPTvaC1nV0rGiRHBdYfPF0yRsPj06OjiN@rjGbrVN6pdk6HXJlyCLXT09yS9lu11@crSDW@vNGIG4APw6fa@Ugzuw@Ob7JElB9G05GVhDyiW4vZkyXKqznTOik4crAp/MZbaNcWdNDvottVZjbXeG9pNjDgGyakLentNtoWb/dXtcqT4wvaO0BxCA24WIJB@obXjJmuWGAISVZ21Gd04Xws4Tu8Xho2rOVQaN1aWgXaeKVt7ob7LFjyzlnj0OrQuvYg7YauH5m2OuY06rDilI5e7sUlr0mUq2rF/71Ev@xrkrurxPUrvEM3BBxGzfB9M@6ysPg5TMteWf8T46D6HfH3bccnL/vmdPR3ZEJbCp1d0T3FvZ3HaB5dzT82Mfp0HHtu6MGzalSuW@8JxIb7x1zNO8674FDp9@/O9KB56yIxE8@Q8eJWs330r7dI24pgJ/P9uTg0waJhA11klz@jlT0sDnalk5som3VTTpYDnEvL9mGf5gbAsTgeLh/fB1NMJr21MDz5/zrMpPaJmRTq6n5MtvBDzdVQHVMUo7oRYbugrwabPPCP5ldqahXbKPGxIrI/LPxod1qbnsZ4KLVWCgTk05VtjmBkM3gXDejz4iwS0bTUaD/qvkMvMlK1MJF1T/5DihtXjw9fHpwfLJ38vy4kWld@Sfjg0LYNuQW2N/4KNsToew@2UDM5ZbYySKDBdnRJ05wGssLysXws0nLRastFW1RKHEH02xe2LaikHEARboC/CSR50ahyKzBi8MOSkz149uFqPBz@mRuAKqIgxYpT6izCsusynisg8i2afvh178yRqH4FboKfocOM/aNZ0NDHDhOz8/RM9jdV5Djw73Dx8@fHbAAwUWjOTd7k2GtnOe21bnBEqinvkm7JWss7ieJQ13VavGHcSBMXI6zCplzILvm0M4hWkAdNAThp95iiU2CDxSMh5Wi/OdvKldxGTf@JyFuPEAqDtlCk6eGsrGxwU6gkbAHzw4/O3jGEP@DB@SNJEIQ7ATPkv/Zj3r8yyCBrafgC3zuiOQrspUjRO1JBEYWFnYgkObUdcfrv8NHX@IgawvhJ0DCbxgJAn0hBtrtOZlpvGbCL0lWtfh3A30Li0FG1ISCrwngGhNaS3Q9dmZ6Jtp6QBz6aLxwubHjtjQy2CmzPfzIIH7KUKfP1ADqU3vCDYT5ZoJi0NLkkOWk2SYhyz9qI0Yixrc3oLF3DBC9mWebIMhNKuwVtERcx6lwWyCSVI/fSBKArpBLQnEtEvGGtUNPabrKu1/9J8qgysA9Afd3fPcscx/eftl/64P7V7j7hYIN7aZ1xAUuUYTQoqlfAo5ISH@kfeTbija3v7IgHBpxDPgqM0dQTWdEdYzOc@B3CdjxAk6i8RlUGjQ3qDHf7grPz3BbCTSpWlEUbFKoDsp06sWY8S2o10yrFvKFnKoAktJZAJC@hTDAs/UcYDJZgW4inJnj2ktQMba3t5mIc0JGrVDlNats2i@y4ssQ0U2IK5wPEbkGgzSQZJECwup@Mhh8UmoSkyL3iqtxZFw9B0YlCsfRC99tnxAiSwCxOI0MNK4/w89wTkBS8k0Ed/DDlZHv5Gz6gCQVxiRyJUXBt1jyqTOB5gOddPElLG6xBLdg8xEQbW96/OO0ZJkX26N8s2ctDtoHH@Tx@5qMPICDymauD6bRuhU/RxDHCKIirmq@jResOWnaLYW3TQbN9IcrGrMN7l9SBmvaLC/33k27rInrVlWRWGz32HZw8ushFIYlNEXLKmohuShSLreySH6J/GygOGj86RKyAzYFLKNrmK@csbe3f3D4ydHT4xu2Rylm/Ho04Pv17VRTktONVuiIR4u1XCX3HyrHT@4/DCpigXQhwo2B8fslUW8ryWJOG0EuzkhdL9oqDK@Xbj3Gn3MrCtfxzWq3oUaJbuChZj4gXzqnID2k04bXM9dKq6iVz9@G0gKeEgG9z4@K30A1kby4arS26007Fr/ZElZ0hBcxeQs7Abia3tamgo39ZuGwYOFno0/wg3xetC9mV/dFcTOLpu3QUsXEOV0Y//M9IgGR8gbZAIsUZCWIurb3HXEZfWGiUuOfteY28aIWvyIIFzK3UTwC6iT4QjZykYWBXd@27FD3hpbZEQJLa9zGbGAKMzQvy62kJZKC/5kWnnHC/2b2rDKTaVNiIoncjmCl2W3magN4SQE6NEp3T6fekD11xtxsP20@eWAErmcOsN8HUz5ZZbBPpiOI16fHM4MWAoFzS5AYKBkPUeWyFHAJ31rtLIX2gCG/Btqs9Qsuj3r5xCwpD41ZzxwAb08k08DRPlLVFgst2mKhyYKtHRepzha1cGtX/BgNAETJ/kFmjWcLBPSGLpt2z5gl4ufxZKUF@aN//Pzzs3hSXNWWyLyyb2@4d93Ocoh@Ub2dk@gTv3cGRoxXcYty@SaXAL/rgLm9v@CbYeWyPPQE@gZkDSX344n7GJwgRiT6I33MElOb20qUGb0mmgk7TUbkpDq3w2qzVIoUKnhQgMwoZZ9cfPxO6PacJZQafiYUfD27h4835pg1VFlugZsySbJN/JbfPkhcaD00KYAODEkqBLaGTQjUDMCIdxKZN3BIg@EQFx5kcXJFMH3ajNZLHKQJlZrV77HItxmXJUexXK74FbrMFcsMWt9NdigrAPYGnwvkeqCub0YJaAbqryzEFoz8JseLUb4xjsgj3/4SoBOL2E4OzDIxgLWwbNwduvhLHNjQV0A@qFSenzxsl5KKyEI7TgPX7OF6Hjf/H6p4/geboJsqS1HjVa7RfYzJ0GJmmxuKQsOND6nDiNdYaixKBt/qcKAse4u2qaq3tno/oV8LEDOHA4B/3rUdgEMrp8FE34qw1cz@pz@NobCR2FTV07Z7lornM1W4qdU8y7OPNpuStNnI1HY3ddCiJq9nTdDJla3cgzNj2O8dDpSmKLIsyynK1sXFRfzh1lPzRZ4VpJ6pFV7P5lfZQvb17Cqrll6fjtVCQ349a4mlWvq0xZ4@/eJt@21SnJ3NX4vNhBbbP7oU1Ryq/LFKmV3sFLKx0zKon5AvY6fsDVynfYb/5H7Ti7h1dHf6oMLGRRZrNoHiqlgUFaURb8E/qfsv4eKKf6Mu1@Wd1tu3yYauT2ZzZprm2Ov14OcMQYLUkscM9OV7wOl5AoU16UkaFF6jWf/mfEKesdmeMRhMD/S6hkeh5d12dW5OH06efOPz4HqO15tnkWRv/I8Hp1IJSWqsmKeotPV8DD9D/Gc/3rhKXzxtb//Zt0aKsYGPI3x85@oJuo/V/EcbGx/dv5/LpTVN4@6n33j683t7e7kH6fzTRn4nJ2U2tv/0TzY2NG1bUzZanqe24o3T0y9ELZMT5T/7nXj76dOve149@39@821dxVsRbmesCHwCrixTwYn3EvxUlLHe94q9iUErV2Nz@mvHAv@LDabWd4r/5XtHr2OTWF1TPnfhOYm9jhVKMe4EB7xlg7ezWD22jdEKV7G5UqvVwFn8L/8W0tc/ATgYMt@GWz0fwCrMY3WpRkkuY/UCOFRNg3z/729@M4IhZxM1EuOCa5c14BJzRU3cacG1Rde2gPYxpYyiBPHsyXBiOEwt3VPv4YsJL/CwDfzQgDFpxvBD7Oxol7FnjVQq1ZLbElzyC5okUlRVa6rqPWAH0kdbtZq0xbgF0Gw2fw@tmCdpSmvgwIhp3Pv8H@KKrfKs/szgngmxwsbuywf1OpQpW89u1VN0@R2J@lSxJDrOrsjS7GUcVJBG6@Vjxs0W18VMSRPT6fRum95nSCtpFrYkvPg9Fgt9sMuy635LSSCK7xv78HixA7z@/H/78@//@ffo7/v0@w9oQNTumX1lCyKdQZeow7VbqXTrdbHuihdNfK9DO8pUSpWS0r5qJraAA7WeMTXz8WU8n40f84@kq4w1k5QaLsq27meP7/XYwrvOfepRPz@ARyYP5peCHEtUI3dItRvxYGj1t1pLjbN6S0KBqCY11EK@JfFU9eAqs8YuVJOoFctiq67ltSO2257xiw03PebEQDMsBHT08a0vylYPQxZv9ahXrB4kqy/ifGi8EF8h1mgoLYMGhMCP7W5UNkqVQkVT2vX1FzTN6CtFNQzjqRc7i4UXp2xsQdBY2DSv@wVVEb6woAWzD4kHktH7MF@qpWxBFau@S2szsQqNRMtK2qAtZlQx7G04vw/XBvzRP1zhK943yMf3pig3rw1WUbe0rJL/qHCg4fh6xxXFVYBxgnU7nc6bbgekDl3v6F1dnehTfabP9Uln2pl1Jt1pl2GXWZ7Rzzp5p@TMGG@AshTL5tXN2D1q1G8bG@wZ50ItlgquZurO67kst30nORz8SZIziwmxf4Crrmoq24LxKQM3EMrICToz/qmqwGIgaF203m413m5BB62ntok5tuqSjyU85PZuKyVdXTXAXa36/9v10Fmli7ugcK2rVGr7RR2kjxf1RgpAvvBByhIjoHK73tqmkDAzPzc/eLsF8ouU2m5s15x9@snUQaR4zokXnN0WAN5eQnZ3NyWDaxcA1DehPyZTqU1J2sCxseGPFRC5VU8FpUIcEiAtXFz8jD9Q9KAXX21f1a8a21dX29vwv033K/8JvlfbN/7psbjWxFmEt5C1NBtKvak0fWbRgndZqaOPrDTBUYcnxGtktVKrgQ645NZ/m/9yenEPfRDllgxYC7EtthVDc5bZ2JYQe/nuy/8Ff813X/4@yosM/oyKELvAbq1sobZZ5kon3Jj9xGZP@GWDG3/BK/qgx5M6etr8ZuOClKK8lFmFz/kn1FIhKeMA3Hb6bbSQIbOXEPUG72OiViqI7ZQ611hsWywUid393I0rHo//o5dauRjnEzVo4uGl53lPIlgu8ITIVS2jSuplnX/FgH9w5udWXf/o59ZdQuyyzIwK0KfrMU4ZIQYNKaYokgQjVn17hIcAcK1EQrX0rPaF9HxPwnkUfUIrYV0@R1A7PKiVy3W@zLP5lLrN1oMtuKvwf7AB5WDNPsRt9mvdEUjAzX42rzXR5n1M6rzGv8dv8I@ddPHv2Wv8Yydv8O/ZBP/Ykw7@nbzGv70O/p2M8O/@a/x78gb/ng/wr/mVbFatipsXRJqUWlavNmcikaga26k3vzJx5xXLsBtmr@V/zimbK7NkrPkVY9Y1xpMK9@zHf/Ldb30rXqvFpTh9JCenOi5Tk1WgPpTIi1d340KsxjbVTTVjZboZtaN2wGGyjMsyw8xQ7YGi0lZZxmCZeWbOMiNH7YHLgL8MuMxMn2UGLGNnbIgIoeCatDMTdPXhMYC/PgBy4c/EPa0dNdNlkJGFQht9XxPBg@uy3RQaLM7ElwbomrIqZ@SC2cKvEjXEly@bylZLK5eYjI1KbjdeNuMtsSmipXqtnGOdubHRfCnC0JwReeNDHxbzPFBgqzGl2VQ4mYACRMWrq3b74NMH7baCw1DziXO0@D86GkVfb/0fHTlPjpyRA/9HR0fQdYx6ajcFDHp3twYM23/sxOrVnWaF2H7A@mPK9k6znpXQXUgBN9fQL/WB1wIiPOsbTSF@nkDd4xzVj@rn59WzKrnPg1dwtKuLCEE07vCfcJ3DEBeoI@dwnZ2jg97Qef55M3Rxh/L5OXh9zkDvCv9BwYu@/lf4N//b@n/ynCVZotFKJi6uthN0JfEvmby4urjy7/VkIuG/JLbhDz3gHZNcXNXRSZEuwNVIJFvJqyvuB/dEcpsDrEM223VKu4gHw0IszJKy5bfEf90nZO1fzXgV5F6uW@cz1I9iYpXpi301zeYsk0lWO8FHOHCVWL@kzQvJKn2BcbPTUFt/@jv0oZWdJEXK56pVdYvxFy2nVau54K1YqlZLwctmIlG@edUzO2oB9I9cLpmsVuFlJwCbgVdI22BvU6zGmnBv3bvHMylpl5cBzGyukMqoGUwd5JSHbA1P7/oM9@LwiL5RAqwmH8OPA3FWksjQF47wK3pxsSLeu5foGbhxurezl7x3TytnLi9Dn/EYvNQlr3a7Z7rtNvpnLy/Ftkj7YMp5eM@ULi/VTDmlxpOOm/gUP78IWSUklX2k1SnXMrBxLVeEYB@B/PZ2IVevF3LgUyjFk7im3kD0W4BvXIxXxdgFlUEtFTkHFKvoHd0fBH0ZBwV2cRWjCmW5fDIBjDQJMuBVDP9c5Ll8uMnnk0CZK5HHVMtlHjXJcoVEKVX2/2oboJWDkMP/UFLLpnJbxa1dkHnxz5utupAnVy@MmnpVuzAqOKt@Ve36H7JGOx/GvXvZMpColKk2hXb7wd7JXrtdE0URBSW4oSdxdwHNn7jxBpU8X25xilSqu1TNainPoD55HCkOIwQrAdEVbSuvlpBIgtlHMz5AEoFrSxtsQ9DoiTehzCm3AZ6gzkDmPbhYj3XYAC82QOWNmcyii1mMh9O92w0jOfzyQ8NXSkv6XeBjhJfg98Isb6IwiD99vLd/cJLWtiUW0x7u7ae14@f3Yyq@5hfvFJzF92cHew@OnkOCp48P9o4PPj787OD5U/D32PniCpi@f188o64V7@fsc@GV@0Y3DN2YGkb7fDo9f81emWbbhMq0plAoZ@Ayz2hDWcb6olxV@HVNT3/1SnfHdLF3P/z2ux/@d@9@@7vvfvvb7377@z/58vvfht@P4Pdd/vzuvynn8f6TL//Z7777rd8Gz/8Avz@C349/8uWvf5P/6P2P4fefIn5/7P8i8fhPAFi//JMvv/c7P/nyV34Av3/p/35w8/erP179@/4vrP9huu/97u1xvvtv4fd7HFYQ97u/xf3weSP@b/F4v/KDd//i3/H/P/X/0Pnb7/7FH@PNf/mnP/jT//TuW/9e00p/@q/f/cL33v3Ct979wnfe/cI/1t79@r9WM9Hb7777/h/81R/@3l/94f9I/z@i@@@9z/@7H/zTv/hf/@J//4s/9H8/ht@/A9eP/@LfQ1f52z/4If5/7w/@9o9@iP//87/62z/4tb/95f@JHL/BHf/Pv/w3/P7Xv/of/@Y3v/NXP/7m3/zaj//mN/7gr/6PX/m/fv0//vV///t//U@@hZ6/8eO/@qNf/stvffsvf@Gf/@W3vlxz//at9y/fw//LfwCf98fzfeC8T7k@1OfLnwmfvw81FrlAO4HW/Uvvfv0XoYH/C8befftHeEIOfmv@f6SpFOdH/O3/Aw7tZpkxJAMu@P3au29/F0n0PwCJ4D@k13fCl6UQ/vKdxQuQ9TdXJPqln3z5z3@H3mJGpU6rNjh2l7RSagv0m61y2R@//QUdSPKLy9BCAH5O30EOtRT2HeRt7374zXe/84/f/fA33v3wl3HwlnLl9F5aUu9YDYOI@feIhxEL7xMPI36B@adoik1KfQFv7As/8IsvvhDalwoexdy9BN8vyItfjAfhUU0/KAhDfzy7yS5Z1O07M75z0/cNc2as8fJlC9dbwQ9zT5HssRWIRvksm6V8xGaML@ugP0SabZFzhnfyxeCZgLfF/8I5E1hq5k/3wjO1cJLDT@dnwZ1CHrJJzcLFJJLVGJeOtrgPrRNTvrkywxLMZqkZKMHggBxSEHQfxPFaLYUJaxwfeOWo1UuMUEmlalBuTM3TpNslBDG7T1AgZS31jLW3ajOeMIXw6gE5UgJ6PRNVTUyVag8gw9rsAUNYCJzAvnxZq5dqszqCe8vpkZql7hNOCKyWmtXfwnuNYEI6IfbgLaBSqqVS9RJmiIXk1ZNu80rKU@Go7CmW8usAnrjdf2eXsY9EtSTyRYINJBiPjffUIjZGhOgQ3kxt@cWh/8BJvy0i@AZl5efCePgOyaY7XFzFCABXkmRZZvDD9fcdtgvBMw4qRdnCI8UhpKhFUAsIPRjOD6WEFNVvil4g/1ht64MvBIaF2dzcFGJ1MSseyUQ6RWHuaYXOPuB2QFQvKkwslEX0NuggSIALpK9S/ptxXFiLMw6YfZTiv93dLfYRFJOeCz@BSamsk3NiHMp2KiVqAL/upIQXoJYI0E4J0KUgz2q0kJcS0mnG5FoMw9jR0ZGPBHm8qAkpaOZaVsV3XE6aTqcxSCHLaTmd9p8yPclD9h0yhfpPeROJS98nZ5qWq4L2VGXoxaKqjgoqMHq@ffsWaoX2V1UOQflk/lYrLVeiQPDgFmksax4cGNJyZYFr5kwt5BhL0BQrXEmWFFiCbSUFviufIxFcibhWKsUpHlBfTmwFO@8KKjUHnF6N1RHR4OIqYSmfDAL3j9j@0ZMnB5@ejFstJhj0vXWjPXadruF5CQzb@/QBP5GhlQvJWKOBoE8qGjIY4aCSIWZ8@ODZ4XGF8UL7VZAgxKq0ruoXs6wKsfH48@2Yv/NIxE8GOuIx3iuLsiW0chaSxupCrGugZoEL5qgAV1lVeOIN7jsz0OnTophWC6jZJWlSmQk/70wZGrTl1m@gT@E5DXl7mygg1C8kWrpAJ9RWQajX/T17TBXqxwcnkODkiKlaRhbqX7CZjBlKV0LdqlmGPZgMN3Hzm9jMiJEybTYyafzTslm4q7lCWs0XWxsb1oWEeTap2i5wF@MVvF5IWIyvwsWErwrsq@AFF@SBWxOZvy/08Kjqb85D03EJvkNPVPPQzZICzmNzcMI4elWhdS8vBAmxjW98Y8LqddCvpcOHQgy4xZAF@9MksycPZarm3tQ1KHTAWM/8zMRvQco90xtb@hy6DlAjdnV11QdIhw@ZVtfolafo4f2qSz4dcF/NdCFmVyq1t2quKGinlcrbrKYJ4CFsKbgBbgMaAO0j2FL4X9WDTLLZkgKcShVFeGSzWQHnjgWhYgiM9oq8zdRqEm@D2ZxKW0UE/LyIPqtp4eXHnX20iJvN8LgYAgFsMHFZJggr8jD/rSDQGxANd8fRx6yrfufM3LuXxUmMbC4TzlZQidkV1M1mNpdFigv//4UHsPhqzva4ns2o28oYnDo4c9uKDs4OOPPbSgecJjjL24oJzmk9q2a2lWldYMI2Nx7L0DZNTZwYM7RVzf3EumdYfRnPFtVEykATt31j7PUgYb1X6zld@hJ9tSebtm24eJKcJ8jlxKpjo1nDGho4obP3LJG8EAa1czrvLhi1gYyWclxbt4Se3HF6c9mbzC08pWM5bi0O4mA8CFhAN0AOwbmvnWw2V2mwljx2xjuCli@mGmoGBhD8qaW0lt4wdorFSk/uWobu7uQr@VK6hweA/CWunXymMpC/ePL40WQyfmbQqaCdXBkSoG05tAK1U6rk861GQxRTDcqmhd/R5uxJ2tiAPm3oPQmeuADmSVqpBYl7plurxeM7WVWT1Eo2U7oSFoRDmmMJ6wImTWHJ0kj3C58DVGzHBmZTSetp84KoUOn3@1dbF6nFi6BfSPwN6HMl6enORfhalSLxKmyalsxFIPjofSD3hb@2VxG1fEmsNqqL92JBrLauhN2R0TN1PAzUzFzcTFUApsyhxiCjJhOuKq7jTCodo@@4xiJiVi0EETlCNyPkxKswu2YGc7y4mV0hEml2cRNKLi9ehakCtISrK6A7JzaQ3bcMXKdNsw21nGsdAAuC5rMdGA3GaLEXL4TY1rPPsvU6VPVFrqjl8rm8li0U8kUNxptyrpAvQWfLFDJ5TQMouXKpXLyCdq0ob2P0TUC2fxG09wp9FSGhV7hZz0aLJd9@aloXpazE8Ugkq1dXsbdC7KNnn2kwQK69EjDofqZJ9Vo2XwZXFl1aFhBmgqZJWlbKqpKaxf87HBr@v398Df41vEOqrCacoK2fT2HYhKHeZo/RZsjEYScOfjVqwO4b3TUx9oc67Wjedx3P@3vEua/bpzzogckN7IZBj3T8dJ43MifDNTGej0doJshw/8EgHIw6gCCyQx7hPtxcy3FWRSiy50/XlPJJaNIeiMFt2kP0Z4cfPzqJPE8O9vYfCQV2/@jTB9ceeT9Snj0@eHgSvhZ5aJA0H4L4@YPHj6@/@o/c0fNn/anj4k94ePQ8t7iFXnhgVsjBtRwp9CYg/g1fSbAEiQIUsXwxcKgCHrO4B8rxPd@ZLyycGXR@zk8Dm1647Z8fDK8IJ8ERYZ0hp@0YrMutQaG2TpYafVleLZYFYcxs55wVM6znWJbuMqff3wDPoY7HHQ0UaC0LWyJmfe64Vu/c7BkbwhM8WVlW8ZvriITwCICMpl2y8gHCDNr9hVHNZrgs1bGmBpuO2VpPeKAXOl1zMIQx@NwJIggdXWfw@9AL0hvRa3K7x4TnQX43Qqyb0YWYsBsrieK@KD7SJ3q96hovql6mUrl3T33qimVxDIOy7g2Mgxm0W/Yc@pHuztPiRBYfMrkdG@DahuWMUQvxxg0Q28tao7WT0@qlTD5b@uvf/NHf/cmvDWpqM7OfkbZ3njx2JuxtvgIsDqRZRgKrL9TKpN5o5VK@VM5qpXSpXMrl1UI@n1a1NGiGxTIoBxm1pBZK@bKaLuXKII3kyhCaLxd9kVgJZGBlqwJg7S5@C3ybNCR5CKoQX45kbxJ6ksX08H3KRAPSiAIqoxM6Qr5l1mAgZWqGZYsMIOqsy2IPH@5nHj4Uxfv4gts59jOi2MOXfCmTKd4XRYNC9ksoWYkOT1NCq4rihL9kMveB1FMOAD9IIIpDfDko4LSaKJr4sr/38CHm08cXDdNDtFMewl@s4KUI0Wx8AUmdALwOoUG0PZ5PjhA9wBfMEkMe8pB9CBPFjwN0MOQZj8YBPApKurcniof8ZW8PQ/ap2HmO6NfwZY8uUXThBbqAKA7AMXCh84liB5zYEUSxC67uXAc//O462qy3J7oozjl5kECiOKPYevdUFNuBP2bzmY9NHqlboReVl3qXXsr4J4pagDRGy4YvWVHMhS85KNujR5/pw0nPGPBr7vJnF0r66FFWN2fTg4edjz/uDAYdd7538PEzDNrffwRSyXzqdgYdP2GnDZcDqfYfafrpaH79glIfttsV3VoZ9LV2O6fb14La87aBGEKq14CZfw0wo1F7H4L2H7V39VXLyQSwjTxgBM8OXvdH8Lyvd3hQcFEQPWedjljF5q8ozYSAegMuBGN3PAWeaqdHetd1qvg@q7FMGkWXeaOQaVUpgI1A/s9UrzC8n8C7jnNAyYt5Y1bLtGqzWlHj@5H6CbE50/KmmN4Y7ajlfGVD31G1XGpWQSsWTj/O4pK6wxLqva03LPFpckcDXUBs7uxIYkNt7WhqqVIovtiaimKygvedbLHyJpGJZxjDW7JRbO0U85EUxWJKV7RKsQgSGdBkAgN7B6dm2onEuaGfJpOILU0UQBGorGxO5TSr/cQsPatxvNg8WZ3V1Cq31cwyN4D18MMA0@7EcTnIAYCb7WQquBKfENVySQQEFCWRTIZMD/R2YbEV9POvn5yenHxBol/dn8N46hrIvar@68eP9uXDo@ANTfrLD1EidVx5H7nWUggXTQOvE9BF5EcwmIJeF/jhaUHXseQD2kEHYm0QEFgVkn3zuvLJoyU4x0PnnOeMxhaqZKPR7hoMv3hg9pheq4NL77EEYcX05DkN4@16vdaujcgeARQxSPU1Rp8DWIA59DjuoQkISn6BJ@j8gHYtc1Xt1GaxGcBp15ikvhw5vZdaqlvt4YcO7tfuY@JqG56dqlEzXNdxRdCqxWp/x65NbU/vG08NF42bHB5tglCBx@oSfWYkN1nzAGPvo8ZyJdVdZi8w@3Q6SuhSvZNc9sL5udADiZP4elDoCzrpiXs1rqr9Gku8gKiv4d3dZImefD@5k6sCne6zdhK8Mi/7L/tMY4VclTSOBMKCrkT0wXLrLFmrfw0eHPZppQLY@BV9ClAxMwBs9igAYo/Nq2q3ZrGExGYsSUTKVQe1Bia/xNu2JIotSWpctoS6JH0u1KG/VucxveZNO/SNHJbpqFqmUJ2Bn1rMVYdQvfqLWdWtjaeuUbXg1Z/W44da9SoQFWgHYN5cJt794jeT21K@xv2qBOrSAgGkLbdrs6qNVjehYdSyNQhINXKZNOjycCumYczXCmm1kM6mc2mpiL4w4KfzafAEXQeEjISVEBkT05lZRlbTqqGmE5mXZu9lMn2aAOGFiMaS6YlzYE9HDHygqrBt0is8gTwpbcsCHaznMH1bosYKLKOKBQOqD9nYTA8R1DNDtyhFMimx7FbC2kxgnM2T6fig0apUDmbjr0NQQnq9U0gVM6k3yWQ1sZGsecZroV4V6sheqNTjDWi5/own86ajBtQyuNSiVmk0OljEYiadzWShdGb7crAt1sVWOrNRUKGKrhixDcb5RnQSECWehd@4jTK4ZUDVqWWtKsg0I5ctaVJZyW/lM3xWkKcUxj57Q0qyRFMMDnAn4vGiFo8n41Vcj9gQ/Qlo4GnEz@LAXeP31B0RhDGxIpY1jLBgjXRGNxNgB@LYlYCSIcuBinshXF1cbdeFrwjHePJyW3uBf8UXT/aO8O8r4FWG19KLJ8@Pnh89FJhCWz5BzKxuVOVquwovklzfFWIVxoCTNn3rUsoGYx@6mTS1XX/Bn008RQBwBbKk3WAt2uRlmKi/sc/QcsEOi0MZdHfU0LRsq6EVYewDbhpE1TS1ivaaYnhOQa5DZcwuAL/tVB0P/X2Nzed6SgqU/ntsd5Da5EdryuI2HmErFLP8CBtOxG/OFIFoF7u2Mb26V9sbPNurMjFbLIrVvf02OMUEi1XFvA@gmnsUfxY/iR/Gt5N1sVTgvmWc1149A1EH4en0VPWP@hQzbbEaY20x75@pi5wHyonbZX7gLudn1hREEbfVxS7isfgV/C0QfvEmODxUAIinme0XwPxiIXLJWJCh1hZfMK96KqmZbUBzl05QavwEJYuFZyhxgdhf28nmCixZDpZevhLfjcXjcVzjqDDvbSy2qoinVTGeTceL6biaZrtFnyrVN2IucnTwRftFjOGm/xfVF4BxeZtacHC87WsvNeg8MdsJPECLxBk@GNzzeVxTiCkvx943tFL2yeGR/cB9GDlq9aIew4@pS3hqrFp50d44VaHTZMXsaTrGdmN00kAsAyoa94AaOGUqYAE1wcTnD46eiDmkV0WNg1cCqMYLAJk2Ny43HFxEYuHWxrf2J19nbBzP5uKMNWuxWS3n75lX63VJ3dbQpl2RVWCI7KsFKXNZ50ygTgEFDULe/eIPcrPtErxrGRXeNS2f0up1dUtjydj43Ze/j@aJLg4@23vM4rj08Hd/8jta8e/@5F/R7rz4FS1HaNliDGKiUy0UYxcX44uLK7h4WD7WinGkcsUkuPnSmBqrK6qWtW27yiqKrm8VUzlt164qfly1qCZjnhTzN6RmC3kpkVAVwGorW8okIezSj6llSvAWLMrx6GIBKgoKcPDMzGvq7vYOlG8nm9OqG9Dk1PDQLgv/tg2vHBNipScvLxmDl269NxiYGrkUhVXeSmz7rbTN3uKS2Ftpg72s1XFrhYpHfYMloy08@ojLpvF6StmKM1ApWb1xVb1qpWjNCVTwF4axZTevtdrmBp59WfbasuHP2PLoDxMFHh68Bm/G1itPTGwlFaXXE2/2hm2D5evQYLaUxYFkthWsJPE/SWom3/3ir2ta4e/@5Fcv25ftLzRQy8vlgqrFfvrT7ak99Yxe/acA4BbTNIFqTdI12pBBR6iSM2671PRThQ65KwqxqY3qB48fKOiokjMQ3cyBbfRIQRfOUNykym1z64i9BEXbQssVaVJfyBpZsioIgZzP1RN30E0TDLaFBncbraRwIXwVg0CaYaDiVIWvLkCBxwjkF6fb9qypO6azQwlKp7bS7B4kgRy@ioYnN8jihj8USmqVKVs3k3KUPaIaiaZsZHgemrGEUVz4KiTxrZJbczbW0TgMxjRtGHtljEJ4UkCvAXm3IG@LJ2iTb4JKzyOkGceOJ7JBhRG@CtIYUcEEIY2Z2xChCvzrq0AAKEPCB2y22DbLJtmFmUpVFzYyr/CUA1rx1APDFAImQ2g9NIQSJK5iPPAC1Qm/g4vtwq9hkJEjngEQDoNviqiB8oXJ6Q3lXrIc896gABZZaUtQ0di9ewusajWzl2RUIoR/ao5xCpHqwV6NKwALFNePehUxzdD6aDXwDZsdUDxF6EKrk7jZ0WokKRPx9UoQ4P@9Gy22yGtVRQFVLIBfX7xXdIFkkBjJzuuwy7ZrTNWKSRYi3wXcu4QUmQcItfHm7CNZ@yIIvAIMfxoLvjIFTOskOi3rt9vrlkkY6CpT/MQP2qfjzMC3KMIt0CHzO5wEqcNUUBTToth90wU9kXZrBMYvE1k1ickWxkIJD@LjWo7hcYB8Eh@UCmMzeOpoxNHPZ4OMT3UdqFBv7Nhk9ZGsUuFZDGgRwKN8g3kc7al9jp@E8@uGEkcx8shYHrZ8xJisWDpo3ofS4naJjmvopwFt0swYyKw76jGtzBLU0Miwnx2CS1IiQrgD6gbSuGMZI0Dp2DDoAJ9XUZQBiKDTDlk3fGJCuxo@NGEEsj3lASewcm6emsoJ2maWnD6e8@O2YmIotWL34zszfEuCluOcMss8Nfhse2LJ0o7HQOECnSENlF38gLAV3PKjZdM47wPiE8WCXxEeRe4spSNpNxLz5M1nVt1ItLFGL2m8MaFWLONMtyP0petS8GcavLkX2Ooii1PwLocs1/Ct9NTiaH8jND8l@FbHamTwSsZVnHFCjImBtS50CmPXOGM4ZyDgGANMsxvYvcFeDKX9Kg0A1PegZ6ERz4lbQWtNgInbS3Sh6/kM3mYfsawmYERuSs03ewYwsOpry9AhDJJiObxJDypGpqUL5CvQO0c9CEM7IX7zw/RB60Y3GVhdNG@24YPDQYfyqjHeLYKXfOQFewe2Zyr6BgQWAMMVmGwkxBSATYlJkYMO019Pzlu7QLykwm5CSjOE4JMaoJCooCPLQSuNkW@3CRBwX/f4Bz58E5/n5@cy2Z2duqZsePg9M8@xdUsZD0wQvR1lYozG/pejza4yDuAuXBL/jKE8Ho53Zijd1sr35vwpCH2v5m@cSsT7XhwHxzP8XNdgRDbq0DicRw3qoUmf@usm/H1cvP1prfRF0P4q2P6kUvwKgTCGYGbpebqbBmDpTvc03T/vVf2AM@qQABxq0Qg80Rq0G7yMvMBljvthDGeCfDQM6lintBYOkEQ@Qb7ImpcwiDkPXv33sTmDRLZxzvZcV58nKDyJsbEBJ@Yk9rA5DPsUAk40fn7BTRObs8a8tZR8FiaHQS3cCeKiATrh4nag3E41hs94@AzCZzx8tsg0yLYxa3GRDL2usDjY6tFuaRATwcyDOFfcpvMihCCDPA4qFflhzPmS3xX8ujVKHdCbv0E91oKGAW1iDAQ3EkrjRbPRbNmecb7VSikDaOwiEQJqHEA3WkTT817oRupbZ9bY8Za8bDRXC6OSjzd6dYd@a@BtBcsYVhA1DE4vEy2MDkb@lhUuEPgFBggoh0EgigZ7k4SZrIZ20SkQGk5DXNCYI9bwkWmR9OUH@X4gLnHSc8JGAbUigNA/LBKgCSEs6Dn865UBd/jcdSBOEFeiD@6N0NJdvBUHSl7rKpzXVKmSIlhJUoAmkB3F1dr1ogThUBWNa0GRYl759R9Ff@OD0e9Dv1iNPTVYPmBUhWhXwV2iIEL43YWoyuq1SL0CBsqWbhkujFwHXD71R2vIZksJ1AyeDxbBOzcn3WEiUvndJK8fOosq2mIlbArzWg2KOK/xbsn7RUBSTvAwmecnmwcNwU/PGQjAyKxMZvjJZtFks1qNMw42W5PsPILkjJCc8SQ89mwNki0/GWhPh8HwgtXTAukUt7GKAE/lwyiIQWORefqZgRsLXqEVTlyU8fNc8BxqBX4bQhEb21m3tTL3RgTpCNO6BgAb4g0APf4h7IpwneGpUvgW8ihOyoBH8Te/GXBeAQ2MWHCVW6pOhI2MdGAQ@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmljHvwz/ienAM/ipNz0zyzHVZc9M@trfP4hnCykb6aAR6UPN5JAhoybz3PZNvEZljhjbm4KCA1Jd59xhiRXCNvgrUz@p0rGcjjLScYMQfh6X@8rjeTLQH3Bpiu2OnYk@cXK5CleaTGp2q/LnOoM5sB38qlbEWj3Iej3H8Oz4BCq16wxs0zPSDA2Jnhq@2mH4n88QonKy73Q8QfC3qnE1FkHzdoWibrtt2uak3U7gDtBkJdzOThtCsXnG4wLqv@CKpAf25AM9GiecziujO0neDRM/veAnOzG7p4mjsR@IU7V7DHhYF@R/CB2CBMM8Z6E5kll3FKU7kwR9MmTojJwBSH1TTxYw9TXwhwvYiJA@HhMuaaajSluJfICDekmim9aTftKvfXBS9jUtoSfD9NoygCVipJl7ncZIWXdFdu212fFkQX7HH47vcRTf49vxJS38Os5cNa/xwA/LOptYQICICzSyd6OBRQe@1buBzhIqoTfKVTzBe6PYow14PcR0D6Lu@dHlPrSPdPjmwVuI@Gfr6H97BQbJD963@nTo9ux4DvxmhHtZE/QhRC9YYU5A9MMk8p6b2YVN@8F75gVx8Ru0D1GEADGWGJeNFqmhY45B7fbCCeQA8B1tHve83Wj3tBGuxgNX4OSepdmptr6KHvy/3X3/Xhu5suff@CkUmwzu0G7bJBBiYiYGTOJzCOQCSU6WMJ7GbkNPjO1xmx@eJPO59/6xL7D7/z7Cvsp9h/vXPsXZ@lZJ3WrbOGTm7J79bD4zuLsllUqlUqkklaqa7aDrj4N2Xud0LbimxYe0YGN5db@GQ9Cx0OvLWi9Pc5cTp9I0DqJLpsodLOO7145zN1tJljDmHt4pZwwbd9MP6VOiGVt8VdmtpnXA0lIO27HXIbY/B@PBWIIedCUKnpajMv9IT8KfxrcJQnSQ2bPsJtU688TnYT5u0j1mhDivl24yfJIbiHBTNd2H30eib7eUOtcqVDW9nEmH@5nd4@G8Hre4wvCkHEbdjyW/xXT35jmL1QRYIsK2v28KmYIMs5hWK29DlC9ze6zfm5IJ@Mb7dL07ZpXmDIEal2RJNwp5uc36hZPByrhBv9hweke/AHgejJrCUKZt2NPSgWUVp1z6A0tr0V9ISScoFhWF5BoNK1fGPFP2z1/jOlt31tmaqrOVqjMeAekqrUyZVqpK3Qvonnld0A06ozukM5KwdqafeWKb/vX6/hC7FZ@XwqVK6Kql66UKCeSlYKlSz5NQXmovVXb4IVqqHPHDp6XKX@khGVtLX5YqZlggw5Be@eEFvmsRjvfWUmU773zNjPxPQWTq9ZYqcZ9Snh/llSlCpEC7SWvEEVuvr5s5GgY0sbFS6SpwTORi@cT7MC7/X6L/JIAXh/ZBIvY4H3FmtazKqUnDmjGkHpo2TOiIGSO5omfz@sEum5XFWVDNMq3x7DIMntTw3FJaGAliSOUTDfolBCE3K7MxUtZMdk90dO3EodzJ6fqZeh7rA@08p59Q5tOkEo7apsub/kqDkA68H54ofBeeU@iY6hgjnMk6M9ACUX9emtMo9HUaF937dg/xXnc6E2FbMFmklxisJdNJh@PDOVQ26A/STMKpuMYQ2mV4U04GJbh3ohhLBT0y70jmz7plEAz24HfmNccqB9RSIgiJJ6VTGWXxvMCyGEmJrLM0VRl8hIIlc2iEB61PHBFvRz9yPhE3Ls8Vd01DpqxUyZIrLSapsAf/YFf@SGqPF691eA37vuWrKXmLvZY8AFgl41pEvva/Q3/vi/5uFGpDhIkKZinWs6fSafV67iw7gXk3qXa6A5Hoqh1npnIU15CQnFYHlmY@j9emVHyYfIiSL5XG0Ce0fUO2eE3wDbpNri0EFrSE4XX646cV@vhp5W5CTWsk3WvPKC0eatJwpOExpknT5uMqDZ/VxUjh/W2/@90dPEx3sN15gMcNGE6QXEb58KrHVi7J2CaxLV8gUssVJYKcj0vjbk4@krjno9v42JY@HDQPdw729z7QpPv06VNHz9HjBD@MWuy1xvO4QGYb9Xg@mLFsWXERtgqH3diOjy76w9GDj73slCwRYU3KgE@1GPbTY9zRssyS5xNjl8pJXouiGtanZBj4KakEVcfHlB1quo6IIMEo/8jXQIx6S/R2ebXmcICmZrPnXwbNJk9fJii2nsXQNeZE3Pl77kHxKhpy8GeJLnaTybCjDrVzoN6/qh2r41d1tft2@6/qw8Fb9b62fwwfDW/ebu01thX9X98/qqtMynQSkRixoCS67gStAOF11Uqp9EQx5O3@YCxyJ7/tyPcj/1K96rcCHFM9j/zLFxfy4vWC0aaUqtNydIw9zJAjb16GI9hbcKhIWsZCuWnz1UtcqlCU94zWtJdY817222EnpLwZrH0HYRCZ23qqG1IPkrw1F9ZdUZIQFZJNhzjaKyywbqi4T/lxdkNgfLG/AomRQ8JItj2lCRf/@24KHtcPXx8puPvYPtjfaRw3DvaP1O7BIb2@@dDYf0n0bBwdHza23iKJM74@2GnsNrZr/EEQKHkKfjh@uYpGc1HwkJ2p0vqEk29vQN0fv6V3vaHBqxufL6FGaumqB@kT@t3wt6C9tJG5iqC@4OIrHxWo/GLt8OU7mvNV8CtOOM1RMNsfZN9GHKl0saSec200WDZpvG3o4UrTXqHs8HnE5VghWFGwwf458vzsKgOcjXjaYaCy27BRwd63uPHgsWxAU0UPCDZAGYOVquIgY0tL7nMGuUm1tbp9@FyV2sSIUL@g6AtjarKRYYppWxkAxbWRRg/7QeWN@APxPX1Y0dWOhpJBPY4/SAb1RD5AFW3AdkSt6hxXo4MriGe1Jh9@uRzs8rGwehp/2PJ5FbuucZJ@4y71VRykEU5NuhxKTnZ5ONytH7XCkItEnB9h1rpdGRiBBPgkmShHiWzbRjmzJGw6OGrQZm8SNxupxA2wE/I7o0jlq46njmEcFPRCCeJ33vV7YgKVmO4w76l1@I@q6jvuYRz8ji/iDPrMgAi8mcYjLrejtcLgvuWo5NZUjb62keQAtMYE7VsIbE0h8EfAEKBCaqXT4pmK7wUDTL@jWTkf9YkjsW/7u52f2Ll91QpSBbTVVv6X8LffHE1kN7VOMnaKjB110W/BkNRKPsrs9Ic0xlmscrgwSMHWRX8wCqUP8@kW8IkTT3OUGxMb1fZzdTNVG@gwWWOv37MqPSMuvqPWM2LK@9TKHC9n57H4SuJIE@fTJCx2d0DHP@tfB9bZmYtDpJsA2y@kCPNZOTY/xyPGRPTPTCI7flcIP7te3dzZ@lj4/WcXMWhFLEgIaGN0iP@JMVEXDQ8@52ODxSH0Lj3STOzA6OoMpbUNnpaWGOUGGK0DL0Ja171obsRpYm48/R2XlCa/88cvX6pSqgDJpOOGRxf5RLq56sRU6XKZU6VNQCzZSciSrM@bLy7DjOX1C1xMQi/AIVIPcgTr9onIfFqEmNadXXVIsugAybq7Y/iO2mSLiiS6PC4c2f1R/Cm/VV3edIqJQYmyyJk3Ito1kMuOY5ml8Hw1BW5nPjiS3/cHtz4XO5kevgvazlxo34VbYfluWDItWbDuD/b3OWBlcvtDYKnt7t2AZZKchhZzesyc7mIutqadX@PPU33HY4/AYO7FDkoM1KrtqsdH1MaDeV4KODaYRCE6Ot6pHx6qrKxPqCzJPSwZ2loMAvYD9Saxtg17LOy8WGmKF8ux8mS@pCzazL95g3km8e4QFVoHcTU9YmGR@EnvhLci9fTMwioEW9@zQDSUS2P32cig6EQD/kprQEI26TSrgZmZzczJ5BNGthG4ppsrurFtw88W1jJ3I@zwcGwDsm2C/HPcLJndf@9FP66YekTBghcpNLhNmjTNN7ROOKKKB5TR89I9OKdbTJfCyF4U7JyhHQy/SmkN@88zFDOSKOGiC1tiXSvHGjXRjxeNmsMGiZgGfFh66kSxaKYEI@L5y3O7Q51k0sunpyBSMhGI9oXNFVT89Kuewpga8TxZjRVye6wtMjYnBstT7M5q2Bt3Z3oIW@i1SfEwWRVJ27lVFf4xVckskarJ0HxmY0wiQV5bXX38LdiTrTDFC38Wtswhk/JzdDmg9X0CMhpHvL1PnNvYd016wgBzSCem9WbATBQkVWfGnJJqO09GNn6Ei@wLETJw@4/YvpO1Oup2ArfZ0GVGsqFzlqk2WEM4bqiMminqf51fHQTyN@t78P31yWBDJpgOfoVV/uv@MAqSW3mWpxzrEzwMpL8Fw2GPs8l9pktAyfM1prmX7fi2nRi8SquQyOdtdks6@naSmN26Zq@BK@HtRQ/hvLG7tzG5vVcob9hN3W3s1dUjdgPaSe1FZodZx5I9D8LePARYBvO@BKYPvsP3MKrQ/4SDa0ASmfg2X55p43wTN6YIac0nHBdKm4Vq2Vqe7P1O1PJ78K3iZh9GKuv@QAV5F7Z@sOvM2lkvbaTKE3LRoJenUm624GW5KH3Dhi4gpUFIb@K7NWHhpoaxlMT1mvM@7KNwsBXcyu4ZW076xfJ6ae1ZhlvXc0fu5cmzU/dRq5pVNPn6vcvoanjT/nTev7juqK4a/HJ22xr/9qtSq0/UY6pr5QfxxVxeqxbZ/e1T@ruunpWYczWCP7JfaYSX9iTurlJLKlmHbzxQDj/wormCGxITXKoeXRouxBW7UfXyZO202quWNi5PeqcbuOQ3Wq6OlsvLeXz4gWZRkjFyMn8yOsWcau@6Br1rBY@nHN9VXw1RfDWEvrz2h2F/r7b/MrUbBwUAW2Da1ps31CWU9wKs2XD3xOsFN3m9TeYqcGwGClJmgW8FleEjgPeTsR3TDgkz6hWXtNnolv@OncxCybsajPqcYvxbgrXUl/BLZsFcYyrxjgJlOQmNF0zcLyA4SZ48Dobk61isqAtlUdfKuDvpWCBOUJLFYfZjNos7hUBU3@U6Oc1EXuC3LoAEYtd/4WLq@XOOZE@sFnm8iwdTDn/IFyZKp3jEAQj9DPi0AVWw5h7xtY8MNR/vZTzIF96jGvE9GTaQz7CmiBSYf6vPfL@Jyz8nAgjhF0Tn8vQWp9a8SJGUu4O8uQDncemFP44ZcK1SOmUBjQVsqa@aAGdLcaYRqtVkou8LNyCn0Ir@6RYUyvw21Yw4vyPZmSR8Tq3fItCSu5STNvHTTYrlrWIFU8xktkix8E1qYKeLlkevAxpWY7UddLuEtNBiISEHHvl@r65/Oa4/OkGdpzHykl6YSi@k0j1JF6SSXB5N8Emmip0pm/uc5Puqskk2d6quqmLlxaOebnmkkiR5N@bljbxRvxkmmTfjrhSujBOepxIKVspPM3pfUh6kysQMHqefSLrm7xXd8zGWqbwv0vXjN6M7KGDjWW1rMsGlXi/s/pjRYc91CtgsS9RUSopzOEtlBlVV38HU4oQ0OOzz87DdrCZQlstG4vCYyW4@f5H1tJLxY34SDbnFODWwZowRi0pc5zIT7pYvLFI9nPzAAsEwwWjKjNxNU3isC48tsMj1wFQrtyCnBjg1bXKIV3Ev8gv@mMGeRs7ky81OXBDMb6Xxcrs5TSAWug@ys8mUlia4LiIfdaPmzCJJ3eNJiLOFxL61CxzXGcgd7A62wR/EcsIWFEZSTNE9TtGUTjKUDfve1YVI/Jr5e/FR5qVPOvagG9yqGpYZPt/CyqQuuI@CaBTBuxY7/omuBoMuTh1Z4bvhK9Q6vMDKKo5bEojWzO5lGrDskfwunvSFdCrkqQNAvoGBSJIQXZ2f4zIZbsD2byBaseMSjrxMrTeWDQ0aM49X5Jp5oOB8gwVwNzy3kZCek9EDSkcDvxV4GdLRItJ@MtLUTqiDwPJ@Ou6NwIkbTWmVTOZfrsLWp@2XOM99Wi49Llsku9bHwSXv8ZPkghURySSswA/javlJJmOdDbfkbLgAgK7aw0T/jngzuA56vSBToxmDM0aktEbB8Dpoe5nMYRAfAgMuWBknk7iH3b8atmRzh5Qun5gRt4QjV47DiMPwi/lZjotbfFbmZnBolZw2U1dfh20Q0Nw46fRxOswHFnATIPRAoctgRER55Kg0Snz2rHFh3eUSG1FEDfg5sc4mYjL0@qOwRT3DO1mZLoGSY5Cksl57AhOqr9X1cTnYm4UArsckFDAImKOkeThk9KH5d@GgdMPMGbtveqZI0q/PY4WGezAMSfomBOZe4WIW7tTBx68aR@roYPf4fe2wruj5zeHBu8ZOfUdtfeAzbhyUs2dj9epgj6RLfJoup@YH9CFbO6KSWU7I1PY/qPrf3hzWj47UwaFqvH6z1yBoBP6wtn/cqB@5qrG/vfd2h0/fCYLaPzhWe43XjWPKdnzgcq2mWCYppw521ev64fYreq1tNfYaxx@4xt3G8T4qw6l@Tb2pHR43tt/u1Q7Vm7eHbw6O6goNy@w0jrb3ao3X9R2P6qc6Vf1dff9YHb2q7e1NNPTg/X79ULGRgNXKrTphWduiJSxq4nbuNA7r28doUPK0TcQjBPdcdfSmvt3AQ/1vdWpO7fCDq4Ee1f/lLWWiRLVTe117SY3L5L9BFeqX7beHdXhQAiWO3m4dHTeO3x7X1cuDgx2m9VH98F1ju360oTJ7B0dMsLdHdVchRCVXTTCIWpROz1tvjxpMt8b@Mc0Zb9/A3sGhTn5PhCEsa1R0hwkMMwi0loh0cPgBUEEH7gBXvX9Vp@@HoClTqwYqwKJi@9jORhUSEY/tZqr9@su9xsv6/nYdyQcA875xVHeowxpHyNCAQcYHYh2q9C23Gv1EeMkjMWvGcK7L3akau6q2864BzHVu4oCjhuYWJtv2K01zDx6PrU2UsI89A//S3ljpTH@6DuDjc3pHZvYeTewxaftgp04zsnZ2lU0S3tKssz7hSslOo5kmTqTXlMuadnB2dd4Me50@7pjGxWTj4zI6dxF4yUHUmo@ZOfHH9P4KF8jlms13tSYtdI@aTce9T8kUGt8qobfB5@VydBsR1QIrb2z8VCpC9@cpQm3@oA862VAPBxDIKdT/QUzf/MvAUcViO9DFcHkfgM3WUSTHJhc4SiHRyJcdEW4nqZJ3Jvg91OzABfMGvNdqYp8UlpGcqR/Rn96X5EUmB@sDSWfZ7ioWsYhlNMLfAlONVMIuEfiP9kgQdrhKLwqCT@f5kl0d1vzeeb/fzjuOKcN5R7QOPM873yh@FpxPFC9Mlmdk@dhZB4SIzLqbVZj4/FmTTOl@8Ybcsjz@NEf84xhsxOcDdk25Kt6s1puW@R@kOCySXKVdW@B6BXcydL7Xtb813mM1V1p5sjHx/VX8XcYW7AXhDZgmvBMud8o/r04lAw0w9sVBJAm1h4xi0Spj7E3izDeU8QKZbsI2LH9orr4IeF4nkpAie@V37ToxGw/DWxt7ksMvD2uvt97u7pLoBLZP1lefrm1kYrdbf3Pl9wPqYYe97HVsQPM46WmcZI2SbVJ8eKRY/tIT9mcGLhaRER7xTafxR/h5iO020pZMEGRoboTYUz2Y6GUD0CGr2AHHg4zh15kjUzNAPtVUB6259G9ZxfdJV2Ie0MYs3TH32i3@AHY8/M0QjxukGUizGLswJs6l1QXLveyuMRXlxQ077kEWL2v4WNy4xTTgrS62n8XtWn7TvG31YiSmjBiv3O1ckpB4MImFMnYVPRnZb9jPiN4AZu9h9OVvmt/o8YN2cMfu7vxoVBsdERl345LYp042o3WjTzTkU0QogVM1U9NzhV1@RyPFY09vJ8eOQazRwKgg3A5sfNOAN2I/IpNVsgXsiyVHfRZOhfMOwNnQHKvfiXNnNUdD2TD@Q/S78UqhBFbs5ESodhPXkTFZPsR@LAw5U2T6U/Rg@P9EmsyA/5xWnAQ9oZblBPBelGSoQitavjJRwhtz0GCdbiTUtD99SMB8tTvmIm6YPr25lfs1RALdO2Pz4QO7PezkZxAATI6NDXv8xiZpFz4tnV5kHV0c5yS91uUgr/RcYaaKKbiFtVOX1S7XnK3gxVGO7DVZFe5RUfVCFm5nPOppyTSxlFcPo6yAc4z/j@Ij3gCJBzxz6YVYrU5yVkmPMiMHtKsla8Jpxx6TSC39euep3SNluchMyX598mUIRaA3gc90OzlUS1@JeW7a4yLPxOqYveDBLTuWyZh8tMu6MzbE7AaA87DNmyGI5jK6wQTRFejsqi@BpvIP2VAElSRWh4mfQYhbxyPS8rR6E2PPO5Pg0Bj7tz2JCBDIrpbJ4YmDD42hfV3eU6/9MaHcvV@zhcWKj476LmwXUZlsS@jyiFzT6veHpDr6aDfh6IZjx1Pv9aZD0Iuuhtp/Ic1n4VDvSBiln6qB2iSrd55mxBU/oxaFI9xWaHvMH9ykywAWouKe5LawpvLEvIZHN82mY3i7XFb550nKc6IJuyVlIj5Xa@rLF8klBNUuQwOmYBjFiwu22eR6cO4QD7@b/vAT5n6oQL120I49k1ogeS9QOqnRYx@PrZE0fdCPeEeDugI7IDElyrKRFhuq0hz9VLOTtmvKJt4x4buUW/L99cRMaqylqKKEcXXtxHxrBepMUGlFuwaNnYWWV1YZlVkLrq93LsbYW2j62FplP/ZikVIRJaL60KiOeBK5GT99wJPe5K8@jDB66AvOuLUKCoShs@JcdVrOMX6wKXgfBsO2vSdKmkzbH2D7jZc@/R7zotk61G7/Wv4oCsa0AmgVw9siw2jm/9K/6DW3@13/POyHPq3T4Ef/ViQeHsf8iA47H/ZvIg7KxAltK1N7nDyLfxlxw4b3@Fxyw3LNFY2CQd42UxgNx7ULcRPBO@cwAkwCwjJ/DyZ9pMVlnqwmhTLp@6dsj1d2Nu4s@7g8q7Cc6AOAFnCbExYUcod0xBeTrMunG1MZzuZlsHA8UwXlO3dY7KUwfkYk4mOYFMYGmSmzBLsRWJndifFJ@9Ztsw/CIRwtBTsBAgtFef7s@oixTVLkR1gKVFR5vWQVlVOUW/ghxMP4bnKvPP0nY08I/An0y49nccssRmAR1zHeliJZr2gvo4QLmweGLKNZEpMUC8/DnnX9kKN43E5CTSeP76IGW/6QUqTd7E1xJUZknhY@iB2Yb5LIaY4dTCpLaslhvx1QQWqjfOluhg2@ZT/Lgx@HuLJzBsG0rSHnLaTvIlWLqIQoxhPmtTbK4lP52yNmZeW@vTZBwOoskzMrmnY@azQXvoESyvyKY63@kIRxdoJ62tRjKRr1B0v3pN6dsmOmZ7ZZtG45zjcNgYXZqjRZPmozaatjPI43MpP4TDBNmmJsaUY8hOUrP8dsPknE22oT463aHH@DDnfRLLGbiieVuL/bMvYxKV7DotdMNPGQYtzhpHQj/n7SpIY375YgGqYsr5osMZoQGc2xPFqgJsgUU@n@FGLu07hP0KNNlEO9baKd3T93EnXSSM64PDVJKSeXoCcct@PSJsmlQQfGF3ATJxpuLKRihfPWHfNRXrlwBifDSBCA0IqDQrIPJTu4SWdN8BFHB@jkm7AWKkMS0dOmbeEQO/2PCcZe@fXmjrZ4aI4L5dMNgXQbQ6JVBeeaB8ncN6fXk@YtQ5kiBQ3xGaSIWzQlmy7u36o/2xbKRxCkNCdrS9@Si8Y4apmwoT92UvMWOnBSlS6ZGlHpgdBk0UBjgVYp591AlqvQ/sKhcDysG/QwogWEfM7jZ1mXgDvvtVJMbRS5bY@RxdHkltHmqMKmFEkYSt5Bfj0URdXlhSsBCARjKl8tEwS4NWXscSjArndszkshqvuIClbLGJb0kb2iJnaeM9JBVJ3hyaqVozQrxzMbRmEmEFIsZudJECGdZXaWBApNdDNxsXI8nd2eJAcpxIb3heLUFbpX0jSMe04IyOG7S04iUU7Kyi1pDubEJ6tOKjHmb059VrJSS5OpRJ8Yw5NCeTJ1vZRKTVW7spIumipJ9HDsWlOJRArHRjiWCn/uH19NsV2exzah1iIjpWVo@2yEV6dVJq3bvF8i9ZwvZRsdw8Czb4ab5VdTQqyknLLPd8CulvjIAL7b/3RrjWWqwUTHCmC/dOayS14WhKyxZjHVo1lY6RpPe7GDArOm7XfUu@Pd3ZTb17OxMTS6DIarpVIJTHxmO783ttXYSgr7xXTuYueq2y0Obv4yfHdWZNkfBBwSoGJW0AF1CQ2KyOsPzyUyBHCgrMhd0BdZsda/6nTsEAw4oUTnUbdJTu0NQfEEFMZGL@@OeQOIQeoJ9mc0EO37WcWj78YXRVNDMcdQVBomwddZc3pG5MGHDuyz45MqBgbBbKyZaN5yqpufMYMgsgl3Frsvdj4n5snZV0G323fVe4R1hqeAha@TBXZ37QIlyYITRr7dexWxP1pXBddh17pXjCw2rwOcmZhMnAnjFx6@8Q@D8/rtIJ89@SlL0wo1eRnNXIZ/aldlz7OOdhZ/D7DCh4T2vXJf@oN8i@k0mZmmej2CkyfC6HHZnbn2SWVxeE9M0@zbuUHU2eh67KyBmu6wLmB82XP3ckvuyB4TN/vxttwBDUsCQ@MEnyv3K4GrZv88sXg96nTuJxU5DIB07HdJRImE8ucEIp8B8AjUw4/oCS/afy3QsN6dcCgiCg6CdUzLHRRookAm87BV/fUmX6vV1OJgeVnValv0UCio2lZN7eDD1pbaofctvP9QXVld3RCZu@N8po9b5uNXtUUweIdzuXUx3KFXSqvi3histdHFi8Xqorux2Kw@39yIiie1LVzrp6f//Lf/@p///t@KNf3yP/CyxS8nP8WZPM8rLrY@L/7wdQPvJzunS4tnJ4uD06XzDXDZ39lreL8xKviJ@ag3PMvkZBawvrIdqVlns/cZXVSZ4IGX/vATSZeKyrWiYk5/jSRyFMvYXCuwvge4R3lGS3gTdGByKU9I5AjoGNvx1DutAAZ4NN8QJQkX2IFKeTlbMRv3cAcTZ4hPVXLaEw/rrNcB7rQknhRwF5dmrELYi4IedsCvWeeV5mUyPv2Go6bm3@JPr6Pzrf6tevQxrx6V1CNXPcpm@ae89oy@OovFELdzJRstB7JZl1KSowWYGaooZEWP1w8ca2eC3JnMIofsASTjpoIzyy04N1798WUZCbgWnWcWEMtUyRYJHzKhSO7zYu8rdctnyvE1m7pqw4pCU69iuDLrRCXuX6hAfiSGAEnNl0KQSp@qxEkf30jGU9F80X2d4WhCDBhkPXy5y@MeH2guWuxpm@fUWgphjth8Xr5ibtyQy9CMNlKk/gQBPlCR5WSJbxIu5ZYyYuVttZKbKbew7fZp5hNbh3EwMrbpUuh3ZTGBWHPbhFvs6Xst2pBbjldUNoyPV6yqspO23ypjFbm86o7Cgb6uwLVjQH2Oa/sqIwk9yoAEjvjsr0yPMN4oMJ6iJrpFgmWNVbuPpstI6Omr6dTBjicnRxYRij/laWx/mRjbTpFviRh2EB5gpGJTvo4fdiPtdWXIxD73h2eIDuh3OKDaSM7NeD8PMWknMO53YqQ9hswm58l4pqbkBkP//NJ3VW6/fzz0xw2atkjzGbU8h1oIF0xAAoNPVz2reQZhaZHuEqZI3BS2HELwgu5Yh0eTvs3Gd07QpWYoaLcrGAQpdmJKBl9SfTVBx4Srv6MTbJSnhHd8GqlFLEteWBppSFn72gwPs6mhkzE12GMnHjjZjKAaj0zDC7rQFSbaSz74JUnehY8AXXdW3wLUVxHWnqF@zE7nQc9PTU6DbsZc9C9uKJkXMZ45FKVYI2U0lKflJOIdsCI98qe0FwiZm4w7o8xCPr/wMdLh3HL2PMJOvmNb/KKvwjgAHQcw45sh6m0vFGE5MUMlMTA81WDLf4LQ6frnhN/4xh@DFT/m8j8@KDonP33snT7Kf@x9@fibw5hokWxm2YLK6cNsI7H0WKGZseimXo1VWmRcDX7spTN87Cm5w2KRgBAp5k9@Kp5@KRJCH3OO86j4MScESXUZMCnOr68I8MUpNHNpLIq5zILzyDGdn/@x7CiaW/kXfSgfHPklLMyikrfpaZ0z7BAovqf765VcOYmK6yulJyvlJ7QSOg9uC8PgCvNtIbo6C25JlYiwnKWp5@NvKW5IEeLrbeRv0MdbaqeENZG7J5G@pKRFqB7mXE8mZisq4wlPUH6iMrtLxRUXJ87j4/ARC35XEcuZvOwLSkwHLe7LY/6M@peox48g1yZvhwhHwspAbER4C7UAyCb4yl0c6pjhssT3nDy1Dd@tDIS6t5izZotev1fQyprjLW1Aicatme56ab00OUanhmhqhC5qZWrpgSpv/vj0P/77wa@5UW5zpfh@SL@j3K@5tfWcPNIDvT02b9e5zdxzZFv7mhsXaQ1Mj0//439S@c2/EBykjJ/Tn81VA2ttnNssVLnIl9zmGj2UV1ao3v/1r/9KbViUFRtisS42XcWIbRiKbPs95l1KVw20UpalS4lY4YtZgCEWhrQ2pxcYRt2urJd4my6nrSquA@35ytij6CmeDbNGbCokOxnGnoI0IylQRQUFAWlMKDrKst0wZhtg3gRN9fNDby2iFcDP2pwjrjI23XgYwWRoUZZF1IF5qZHW8/KwWfoxG5t3VLLGpmTDqJBY2mlZu/54g9jhTT8Yha20lYQZrpct/yY488CHXtC@ojVVL@r2fxkWr4klL8sr68UONveLbMddHDCkwmDs/UaKoA4GRAtDNjp11ZB6oH8JF14uRwsihX43PpMy8SRJyx4ELdnDSsckpixyx8@V42E0x0tU6Tz/JQUekTN1IEgrVtrHHpU8OKyo7HKcUfLxmtcBNm/YOFa7wCiINeyAZZOX4TZgd9C0x6sNz/kSEpeC13XJ4vntdtPXafnMQtaESnMzCxdBd1DNdsS9O3yn4sRE01/UzDuhFELsIBQKLOgA6zIY@bREr2b5C9bjSQ1wk6LPWmNXcQlZOzqvXtW3qxx1ZU7VN1L1DfUotISknphnLG9sys4msqWKrcph0MSR2syKqbbIBG0eevwDDCLplkYH1xJ0c/gGJFEtaY62KrO7zeW1MPHITSB39mRrUSJXZ3LJ5UfX5JAb1NCdUK8nlZGAgBfcCiyU6f1IbkBUTZjRsJcRf34Tyca/hwbDbTiAK1HbbZ04H5VpqXeN2DfhiO9SKiKB9itr22BnZPaIQccutuIQtFlsvGQdsFSnwostzmi6o8JhoI1LqGxW9qlOWioOL9vR0WslUAR9yJbKK4@frK49XX@GKGcLurWzwaCQh1XA4MInGKxR52mRje/VanYpK58Qgnq6SkCfBRYHcDDrunEc4/b5xnlQLZc0sFKWYd1wGA0prrcrGWQCcRh4mBFojZIfZvP5HysnaNjpx7bzhf4n/jb@AZnhjDtaX0hv9cObxDNV5lIcDlRZMLNTnPxjeFBxdIqdN@h3DuFtIoCtq7A9VbQHDxCji2H/6vzC5g5Pu7Y6pgFDBGe/1FhBvQxGiYMxCyvoonrDoWHdvqgaeCfTLYBRLqYE6HwCnIaZ9lvpa0tTjI4lmoTgWRM3VnGEaJmO2uzM3Nnrq/r@ziRiOTsMHcP1bMtWUu7YkxkcyCBWr9XcY6Ku9nbBV0m1THJTXpVZwJWQr8zX4X3clW4hELVFFSOrWW8Y5eeRpcy8mLg2TYpSPwKvGTDLpW@T0txrNa0AQYwg1LtJsRBz4/Mcm2QJTnYnY5yCl7MVy0b0dRhF7GBOV5Z1tEUpZ@KoAguZOwBi36aUlYaUKuhRfqxz4GXpbQRzlFvR2BrQZsjxSjWYmZPDTLDVbSQOsBF13NAC7W/sb7tqp05/dt/vuFCUt2p/RbvjEM9341vW@JYrqrFrusD2Fss2t7CZ@hVXlIhZStphbIIghG9HoiIGideAemNX014G9UlqbJ8mXAF29bUSbnZH9SCBoxfeA1nQi/fYFQdf1@FvFdm8mpY0sUsVPSxki2v@wLZospDUGkMSUt4DxMokiNhRS8LtCwnDiwU6a96@XrsYxm7szubpFMvKgorU9t0ikT3Ns3dSZh5brGi2WKmgH@fxBfPtXN44Czp9fRctZo5v8MaDP8YbhfszR@H/C@ao/3O447HmjscVyB7hjthtON/o5DDs/RkcczbmObjZDs9D7A91rFc0ouRaAFjgAUPcIaXEcgltu0OcqPzshOXJ@QhGQiuruBjwhxr/RDf@SQUylx93gv9XG1/4Bzd@VTd@tYK5ZkbPa9XOcrf@j2lxohLm0x9mdi/UXcnm/NGWrumWrlUwm87o5v/rLS38H2rpU93SpxV4TJADB3FfP5@bRROpHW03Gom5hZfRTrvyiGM/mysdrL3a1SwtHjrdq@iiCm1d/WH81zX@65BG/IQwdDiLiG1D47W8LE/lsrxolrzLoXDJSloi7TWe0a326gkrWY/oCUqENG9sDfVChRRyVxKT0yYv0R8T6RtPPvfFWWS7DpaJg3NrAS0rwrKTDHHRfHWQzJW1eF7ZYR/Iavv4cG/5vwgZLv1P@hYaIY@uvQm6XTOT2Euw49jrlG6M1RzAPtJrjhSraHIysiN92ztml4W7pRo7tpiYF2cvEuSoDed/tJa6hL5hReXGlhHRxtPlzaoKprlmeSFfqO2SaXaTdYv/EJc@01z6rKIO9cLgLlL5esNP82KyTltZXZ03B0gpDz8YgCWX8s8ZVf8b)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/fjax9)

Command line: `java -jar Eso-2.6.0.jar run -l Befunge-98 -s polyglot`.

Eso Befunge-98 supports `HRTI` fingerprint, mycon supports none:

```
@,,,"377"( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<  IP
```

bff #376 shouldn't work because last `>` is skipped with `#`, but it works anyway. This is a bug.

`'` after `221;` is for fish. `x` in `#x{` is for Red.

Comment: ...How many flavors of Befunge-98 can there be? Lol

Answer (score 4):

## 402. [C23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) (gcc), 16936 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';       # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]























































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata_;re7^0::Prullasge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=2\0C05+---<?ML42yalet d=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4oequ@  :!?25:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({64cf6e9d-b164-405b-a844-f21caf252402}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0kiwRAAHyzyOrq6urbfdUvdVffey2SzQZJkEQXCLABsors6uqQNLtay/bMejSyQ5Y9vrJmPCuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzkJgGAVWdVXtje8iyoC@Tx58mTmyXMyEwddwx/99KcJvNgT114MbXfKpqY/ZX3POjE9md1esFuG5Rc0XRAw1b43nI1NZ@pXhQRTGbMNZzgzhiYbWPbU9LLMN03WNW33FOI1xnZnzsw3@w3w6Yw55im77/SsPkBgU/fYdKw3pgdxecbumPbb8dsp67njseH0fTbxLGdKsQXGnhjgGcx6x8zo@lPP6E0t14GoImPPHdsYd/sGo@QTz@SZSgxA9Y4pz2pMmbGHruebUILbM33fxcAKBBqe5T7Yf/TRhfRqjn1kAFIT25xfKF5V2aeW6fUv5tDYJ0d3714M1dlXJNdhdy@jpObZ/mzq3p9ehF9g@0PTMZgmV2TtYmQRiDk17XKunLsYVYL2NKdWb6UciLhredC6RtCKrGc40FrYljvMHE@mCybx9jdsO2pbnxk@m/kzw6Z0zmzcNb0woT81vKnlDNmpNR2x6cjyo3yU2p8YPVPqm7Y1tqZmn9kWZHIHARQA7fTZsbk4dT1o8gCm69gLyGj2rIGFWUI8ACBeqenI5HDGxgIa2ZlC52AG8wEN2wyhpYUEpL9jdmdD5s6mk9mUAW59yze6NgDtLljfHBgze5plXYgDIlP46ch0gs4M4GQAceRyrF7NCDVz2eeNfp/loB8DHscms4BqhFaV6TqEM9cDqkGqEKMAGPVrXkdzDm0GTTRwq6yQy0H8YRSC2Bq27wbIrKKGkQ6MVWozhPvEc4eeMQZq9E2i6Sf3nzC/53rggx@m5ePpKjA9Y8p2d1ny8NGdJGtEzSJ7XSFqojo7gyZIhJHsxLBn0EPiLeFC@3hRbgGbLLmVrLIkkEXLsXye5WHYlplWACKpuQo4YPxrugq/ItPKLK/CCCowXSsls1jWwDOGlm1ySEOEVMLOD0k0uOfyTFfLPOXQtQc8WY8KLDG9zIolViqwEtwrrKJBiQg@z9RKAX5F@AG0CqCjwk8H5HIaB7bs/9Bfsc8dsIExtuxFUAIV0WMFlZUAKuCtAnStDFDgqev40@FHqK1ecdjTEVB9ZJwAeMm2jpErmRFjwqZU4KHs7CjEGZH18uL9ERYPJATiFcqsBMUXgRp5QAEorJWh@EKOV8QfmbYdZBv5mI2wLeXgB5iXgBZlaIUc0DOHBC3BD/zA9zRgcBpwMw0YlAZMRdPArWMRkK4IcUVo0mKeFzMy/GMoiJej9akBgLMDGBUpjsxMRSIBBGgxBqSG5s5Dh9CxQxR0BvgDLqUiA35WVlk5z8olBvSs5Bi0jwp4YW9RgY@qgI@KwKAPqNAJVMBJBWqrAFTVC0yIEVvVMR7y6pAXSKPmIU8e3NBwahF/kA96hwpFqlCmplWWnRFw0wpQ34JOvVQrQuuWIA7opgGuGnQpDbDVyhCPectAwzJ2Yui6nBAG0gFaBbs99EUgRgHwIbiQFtxaSef0M@zJyOgi1@Y5uwPMWsThUEQyQtYcVg@eeaQmoJIDMDgSAH0NeoBOowae@ah4WwUgTQRv9i1i1LYFPEyNKFTKUod8ZUymS7KpRcJospiOojCNh7nAQC1ggubQ6C2iSBiB2ShyGVrUMVQjnrsElMtjqA8c1p359hJI5MhrVJR5YtnLsDKF9U2jP7D80bslrnkqpGsaU8c6XpZSKGRjRDViEUWMWAkq6fG0U0uCaWs4QteyLloJ00zcqIFWUFZVQq9rDmbO0JQq5Rh@FDOdeVOYYJZlVniwZw2HMDcv4ahZqiZNmMvgAmFo6/pUiAKRulimZ8E0fpP1RiBYRJEVDr9SWcLQNYSxMLo4u0sgjcFsUMH5a2DNWfdmj2aPJYI60ak3siZh4urGxLHGpULm5WKsbxDl3pRzEXvGqy2/ci0nlWTJtHAuwJzDJcz4jA0T26c4W@H8i10X5leXpIcl@0w54QyZBqKtTvYw@9rARqFRegbOxDgvmTSvhnCsqcygEBAHTfcExVeaHFeK8WkC7XoorYK00zc9j2FaEHH9LE21/qzrm69nKE8t8RrA3G3CFD8wLDtCgOYRY0qCADyTPpS3WEV74LljmmzGOJXarjvZILbAxH2KgO65p@YS9eW8bkwmNkhPEG5y4Q2QOTVI7iYhPV4qRwgyYT5ocABIRYHUYXlmj2gfVB1y6yCfrKJYZVrjpo5QbsfEKh0GC4gcPuZxZrZdBXnH7DG9ofTNEwVDuOi1KnIhDqEwBiJVAKJrgMyMmBMWEaSbmkxi3lHYsr47Xq0an1/vR1UfWSgg2afGAlpvAFOrOTfGINkzFJ9h5LIx9BjegtgSoLtgte6zvuskpxGUUw@EWah0VBMSmJEmU2tsghbkQhZs8TwhjbM7YdZdQFcmauVlUns4JhcIJQsXCcUD8rEAPlhA7OvPekg1LNtyqAeBqOSjrO8Bq@RhwtRjrZYBPw/kukmg6cnowITPELWYouDz0R5I4D2CiLKq6figXvgys1APg54/dAfQ2U4tqDswLMi6hN0jIiAJoqC53JMFIjl2oPGxzSzWm0wYhMOkBN3zbq4Moqj7ymJvINIegSrRm3negs0n0BLWGFJNe@5gAL33jTkZAQg27rPeogfDExoZe4/Qd4nB9Car1Vz6tk1I46BycvDk59nQBLKD4DpALRW7/LICkwlVgUhhOFyodQygFFahN1kQWYTEMsfAdWUM77umT53F9Y6joY@F@eaQhgaMs8GSGY1RSIde6pBy0QfOEwwvhI8FCmsrg0UFveAj04Gh04NeCYMemg/bdJ8NQNmOibCobxi9njmZBv3EJXZmOTG5//FdlPspVAqAyf5I2L7Fdi/0Gkga9ZyYLIt6EKI@CdQRA3ltoNFLJHhEqifnLPbiUvGQ4uRC6eJLTLOCwUtxAw4TGhKoBBGTmE2RlSB3tHoj5IVT5DYkb8No82aXqw9h8eK9MZMGUdmIjQpsR5CVKAjx2AxDgp99GZA8sRFWYyUAk64EXAPa8MdrILsRknY/HiorhgxM8TqgY9dx10AFYkZwMclqDLUFdcZnyDUMO@qMNFz8lTZChr1cZMKJDObQycT1YGRwprOgFQVqsljvChTxVDRXpGV2e3VqhSkjiRP@FGdByDCxDegLOMRwpIJmZQCnACbGFWXgeS4vMYYwjXqCFeB3SqyfdyaYSx3HROXM8BYcCFQPpmcoaMEszwM2eIKTBJ@DwslEpn4Kc4LR7yNnRXLQuL9YuIw9@mDWteYXtfEeBsqvfOHE8NgAFXEPhA4YRKnkwE@maxROOWNRouJOpgpl5XcRElIiGZo8NQDdHiaJu8Boni2cXkpcGWJilomz6aAspsGBGbmMxj4GVeEidqg@YKcZH8O4Jl@NDWH6liS4SxhGmGCEImOE4YGcAYMQtMxKpd812FvgHh6T5gdcFQlVElXOR2WZTj8qKyAE4hKvr8yL8L0eOaTYrIY1wORUc5okVgj4gZSgjCIEKEowt2IASXs8juQaHjhzaD2OpbgokmZnkfALE0CKkLFA@LB61rQTiCs3b4aCy1a9Dp0NpClgm/10XKMNFy5l4NSQWCZpJChEnrrPpjg2UmmoLyY@59iA2AQ9td5gZ9ORByOO/OcCJAKyCg725JCwQTs/so5n/YsN7WAgJhJx1IHQZPWmYk2AyZ@PhvpVVE2uUBW03iRSFTsv5ifQlzovhWKDikEyz/RR/K0HqMRaOIUYBH11LYl41iBs2aEPFj07EAm4CwY750ZdQP84WNCKGFE2kAnCQXtppHIgOBw4HPZk/@hePRiLPFLpWk51JcB2e4ZNwduYXAzzPrh/@@n@05/vrIFhW93qxQDFypeLONXO5tLQmSl5Watux2EsAd/pXA0bM66mEYUgmknuPCYqLXowucxDcj5@@pWLJAFJCMlBJYAbfxdEGp4GhC6ha/ijC5MwG2YyUGSUJUzLpPsshBk5EHWMN0J8nszevMHGu4jUJAhHzOyZwQGEgcp9J8wnY@QFASyM6g74jEh5QQq1HNxwWLriKUN8PkKp@SIyJErHusxHj@8ePq0T2GBdTaIkij8FWcrw@jL0eXsGKvi6NMD@wNVjGXmJOMrThOtaAvd6KwReti3bAB8AoK4ju0yyx2HV/BHgfnCxbhQq9aIeQH6CcFGujMtDvS@KaAwPnOJ6qPKum0UpYjlZRUFrZ6wodnXa6hUKZilfiU9bvWWZ/ThQ2hyAeSCUGz2IOvYlDJGXUmQgVgfoP3twCXGfhEhQBaQQM99mMpXl2wJqL5LFkr5yABqaa5vyp8TxRCamFSUZ7g/IPZ@Uz1j6w7k1TeXS/KmmIS2Uvr9/X7sTJg6WrGklg5QG1MVxZvIGuM/X86GPOK7tDl22A3m4dBgWCGLTxmruD13nUgsZGIhVTeBWIfBfXLgxJjDXWG9IcaRccXWVbzoajn8KXFot6kgkohCBUii9/Mo4MYBcy3o/u/@1Q5hE1EIuF7lzdAEJYnmIXOjqxUIpgElQkBzgs7aC0bbhpdEeRkixfTusdMDoooz7y@i1gcQxZWVt@rUofexeovgrd3Gha0EI71rgiJHs/qMnD@4/Ony4/1lrqhUKK/58rlIEwkF5XZCF5BGnG47WHT40sVoILgFjw8PhBVxgBgpKuGs08z1g3DImkTkCG3oN33BNfeyOnKSfvliZU4yVXjk93oUe4uDjSYOMoGj3bVRGPL5rjfM59p/RdDrxq4oCo3w068qgtCqveq5tDBXKBxODbSsqqi73H@O6hr8uByDjL0yegy9ugeiwoBVEwx67oLzQ3jeyBpbi4GnVyraGI9CFcYPc9NJy1IOpNkofNATQlZWobsSAyQe0DZ5hO4m8a39Z1cq8X6s5La@IYbKV4Q9ptwYmqE4pmK2AFOkLXta62brJFsClEdJFIAkm79Aih89wLrAZCJK0aop6fkgc4ha4Xoq8gmj0eoarucCllEIuX1KLBQXUMlDTQGaVcM1NGhvT3kiauhLAk9wBrRvEeuHA7xnOQN4JHCGyIPfdgKrqzRetltMGAb11k3DD/efmot1U2@kau5xlJ0ifrkHvXake9t0wAPouOaFr0pNt4Gd94zI76xs0uvpMmY4nwZwjTdjDfRCk3rjAr/tmfOxhBiUeqeyspFUw8TtlzYKQjVkFvCGlFBhQMNNC11MQLwmEXhQPoecA34plYMvVjEhgWkxHwD90ljogV/qyhIvBesA1VlHBRWF5sgCWR4mQaUs6IhRGUIETDgFRSYIKhBIPxic5CvyoSYyVod6PQ89ykz5t06BohQu2/gTakda7ezhR@LhEOYUJOhp8OFFA/8J5gp2aSVzKN3y@YAqZguMGYX5QFyMItDEQLYo70QEL6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV29FyoRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBDj0AbGECoJmXlF9nlFeEkUslqlY8c9dRBa12RlqWtN@X6DO/Nw293qx@sGyXWNpwFoVLnY1EL7812zxxd6eWaqBeihBhubYxdXM0DAI25kUhUMvreP6qiPi@YwsnMSbloCfIndOgBG2jP5kpU0Rj0OevUhS049ZV/6mmJIb2BAXSHeYeVjTRw0@lFIgNWTFrRQEyzCkoDkjinRp7Tkg5G3Q4k76FrYs0Sj7k5M56LayZXSVLpGJyKSSb4PdZbc2tpKVpONZBZce@DaRdceujLg2iOXRC5MJ6OLcmTJhbFNyoFh7eR5M4Q8T7exD8xReHljTVJGs1rV21mjqQZPDZ9paAqgPKSW8AFwkul6HZ3ptNg4xW0jUCFidT/AvvOs51mTgAQfg0zC/fHhJQbDyzNrqB5fTZFx3QO91UQpN@UlW81cq906a/UzrfNkFnOna0YdVFTgn9PUWB567mwCsmMzX5WAvaaberVd69aTueROKlWWbCjISKdvlNMZg9M6lTShT6VarSSQNKBOszfyCN48q6XTEaEAj4EFio5tp5LyWRnK76bb6UwS8qaTWZgZ6skk0IX2PH2qNC5K8E5015oDKWFgwiwb39YgHk37Yzhcv2ZORgsvniBa@ANBHxfxl8dm8HQRTiRxRv2G54/LlCuLDaHozdOBfI3rhyiyTRZ8ghE4pi1l5ZBWOPWfSIOxOzWUT2TQ2@TYjJ3cSiqSBJMxxXBIVO2Hlo9D2HBMd@bHFzvXrsFi6RB6NJoBswxPymWhV1kTweyNXJbcvgXQWbTlhIwfd88kvgcXAuj3ZPghE0XBCPdrQMChs00W8EU6FUYLQyohwVlPuD1QKE5ey1FpNcrDcliQNXRcz5SAJJBDoINcdDxQaIRb4/dp8e3S9BPE0qyKU5llAke8a7sG0Zaz69iW1GQcy@8MMctTsy/YwD8GwB5l3hae2Vd2BNoodr0RzBBQG@TEWtRa4yBCcf1JX57OIauQwjk/HskVTJB7T1lf07RirzCohnHYK4DYI2gkVIwd0LLDKEmFyHTQyId8ZSpcJnj0@M4hX76h@R5neFzK64zd/gxE20B1e2o6wyw7hP5kOe7YAjKE@d8c209dd8oXGsCzaXGI6@3WeGYbtOx0cWXoynw9t@vatBp1VdZl@pnnG7bB18HC2P1PHoK68fzoWV2uxhIpxsn4yrJxKXR9sZye9@PbnrTlG@5Q@bxjitsFEeet8AAqspkgoogRs@D4KbRRGF7C8HBI4TZOEF7G8DEePQVxPVjIIG8UGCSsUEI8jopn74LAMzV3juEb1cAonUrpuOy6xPZM1Sj8ZDoYrATrFHwsIWuyl8F5CubHUlfU1DhKBZ4Iz6iupIkDKlKa6KjqxnQlSscP2MjR5ubD6BzEyLTD3c2nILHgDh5M@jbKVaA3oZbAj5OaIORPcKOGWDdu/7EeyMH@JSkWBttE4qmFxBYNIJjcFBRphG2FBcvvNRpCjhtsm/qcrbpelq/s7Db4RjuqdR7XKBW@MbDdARC7jVp45m9TMiwpmYySEVTCDXJQNelswaWqRidFfFrvFyhLTfAV0GjmWk5qzUuH7bdJxScyDJjYas1v5LTPQDXCg5vbN5WhWaNjVhvoVQtjkoEM210wCSQ@TMXXznsj4DMsM18lJbTPzBm4dl/iG3XQYRhX8bCBgnMS0YHS4NywaXnhWVI6zMuzIn@NHUO9BPdCkzYuJ4gdXI0AwfA5Y2@PsydvWROmvBPZn9jWtM3O5anbGQWHtZyLR1y5DOp5xsIXgmM2dbb/9KNPmrk2hyCMDdx8K/NWnIcnpUFwBkEJj7SDCw8LTa0pSQJ0GMLC@qoyIDWnfRpAH2DwAmosKiioEaL@1ny7rMvABGU5ZSLm/mKcZWb6XB7YxnRqOrzP8R3QzeTmW1VBMXUqfi/Y96iyHG0OgWRqYRygWGPPju4cPn0qQ8/1U8lD3ESqwnA0eiMQUDZVOqRkvPJVdqOfZDcwTxpXDgQYaqB9dIL80Klr0OlB/4DSkXcMTS8FgWnc/@lBMG25UUYuoQUEwiNfvSnRKAKWMtNQJwJWXYv/c4erWgGeVejxGaIkkDt1swq0tdLyzLFeyz5MNCS3QpJAWYX5or6dIi62raaDM31j3L0GDYuERqhBs8mkN8DlILHI2u0aP4YAaVEB84ZIXVGkpqAD9XU1bPo6BINIQxCC7PV37EUzJ1Xame11oOh8W3AWntc/BhchrIL2zbXFbqdovF8ayBwHvh3JOfdzUqcvvAhSZdvcIfJlb0oentkipkNHvFaPaq0eBINBhqyEVoOwIiFLSARvKgR9luKJ84POg9koIJVmZxHRNSQ5e/uWaMi2NUY0BJfKeGOch9onMKYHLtTmQfCWQlw6oNEanGXBMdsSxFDNWt0sxhguwisnF6RT6USM5@PSoeUcu7TlFLk6OVktoEQY5R4f25dz4jlYuq0kjXDgabVN2Pnj7oBuaxLQzkuwp08BtKYfyMIgRBrKU3rQ8v6aklfPsawUG5yQpZkW3Ex6fU1KqVKmxINu19qUFIiAR9PC55pkwKSwP2tyXlbD1x5wKQbmI2BcXHtZVv3iESi2QvfgKG/w/K9f7wP9L7fOCCYKXPyMHB2YurGlpMHGxgqyoodu6xuWr9HPbMsgwpDrOpA9w4MqGXbkWA@azgFIEkz/Y9zVCFoc@ibeQGq8optxzPmmZPhcX8i6fT0HWGZvU9oLR8J4UbQDBYpdn4jAhSDLpEzEungjmHO@CxRTsZGNXY9UeG6LUWfm7T6aTWf8DoLrtY1oTfB31dgMUuYKRlc1FX54/oom94zjWd@VJsfDSE4trkm7rD1tQ0sgDgQ70h10rq8@ryA/jB4@NyVbTm3KKT2u6xW@M/MnUpe08D730UAYX1GCZ/P7piRW8B5h5NhMNcum2wf2xAA6dJTgQIaCx12lGNGsC2S2je4CZZDRF@9l0eEG4Dj1XiaT0zfsbk8mm/OjJkn5K5X1uedyj9Nj3RqBwo/USnwVjSocHLK9plVhurLGhi1p/ZhzIzNfdzbiUtJoW5Xy4Psf9BLIlZ0cJ6TezDa8peuKLr7EI9xG2LQiHUwbT6yeC@LAhKklWdXCqSM2YRDLDE/nLQvCE810i53AsNaRMXyjRYpc61mA25viqdUNfeoDGBo/LYpncmOdRHY3UarnnuJvo/gwAtWU39fPaG/WYvUBzEmye7YB8/jG6WBlcRAXH6/pqKeWb9JtPWGP1yI67dlrw1eHQLjsF1/Gu65b@5bt@uwZ3a8i0NADKvD7@g4dp6VlOBIthsfdV/Cg8JjFskENe@jaxfJQMeC2sdVn3gD5fvD8UA4XcShVvYZDheKP66jBcyNfP1a84@saiN6Z9PCIbcx5xRS7jk0Fey@baweKAW7cra/Z3VyZcsoKX@rbUDBuuZwai/D5M0wdm0gbTh2TBYnTIN1hhkoZHFOPi9g/S2n5q0vrfxhTugS2dF0lYo17bJswWdH9UpMyLad@wRxqLvfhLGpgz8yZuVbReNx9ZeIb/lcoGR@OVC6oxnawUo@bA/h2TJTqTaAZfhDWOE@j70pmYthWz7xelFllahOQvieoOj8BxxN0XM4xdGaTlVZd0c6cp1eTbDQJh7TbX8EOY74oHypfIymtyOe@Sb8rNSau4eEZtXohl8sFAkxsx2XFc5UmpUd5X1n8vlIwhSxLXqbFXTYv5lxfBpElfgpyIwvSNin2lLhSURzLMacLvH8gN@26rv1FWgqYKr6z7IK2KtFp36ta7JK4E7zHwpZLFz4ueHQHmxYt@GwT6JZAH1Sar2r0@JbQB7WmhJueY9yQWvVevXwT22C6rhR8vxbXhPj5X3uzLBmshqhyWS5dOeq4hOp2Tdvgj3kxfxW8iqxfCW@VaQSbtbi5y7d0l1vxiQtMabIAYll90FJG5tgk7xVSvtFHax3BY2OiuYu/TdFz0@wp80OztynBxAK@4OB9ZQ85JixNXQf0qykeNUQ9xcbDrEHoJg4c7vqtJfL9sTE0ufmYqzjlcsECT9NwtW7pXL90UeUnaHqQbWkXZHOXgEF1bC788LkW4MNFD9p1Nr5@ue3C4O/hGugHjPZNp2gvT7HOyB05I3PEj65Hvk2DA/rjlJv7uQp1wHo4wtN0k8nKKfs4PW3Xtj@EnsgaOaN03cFanA7x/Vt8eewLweUv@wePaxfvjCnnHejYOGpG5gzmJd@duhNTIt@mpDYu9PD7Jh4ablL/rCtIV@r5QJHw@bPCv1a3HBrudDKhR2diz3y6UVaJXpu@Tm4a8KMpdC7T9YbyG3fclYNAOTi3Qlvg61lM15r2RvjeOu/Z5tDt9kbWdUgHtjKUcMmHez9Id0XKWEy6g8GybQF5vYWM/aUej3@Gj/ubGj1YPeLTWuS4Ql5Zt0JHb4ZLE@O45/PVUHSxKi4Ix0Yjf3@8Sm/gV1/PrOkSaOwsU7S8y7cl0LEJ9@D0xEbJil7TWLLh4FTFxl5KQjoK5JKZA4FH3VTs6jm32BDTdX7bhFC8loRR7FzKFyF3cPaHVget2LothK/0r5VDS2snOWc0G/qXGSZfru@DiIa3zcsWdJw6tmQNc5bhBI9NZNZsBd@zhGcHZK6ZeeWeSuHKTRVKp9qS4Vrw6MADmm62cQ3NtiY@vzNpsHErLjjLBLr4xf1CTpvFemU6aJi@OeBbIOi6TkQcux6eRAYZROrhTjquoCMz54IXZ1yOOwSmLtlsmThMu0lsWXtMaH3zR3Om9Nkjc2jgWesH1hQPa67pFdRl1x0vuhb2V2eGb311BjXb1NnQaATfhvTi1gXQtwbeQ2No9e6tNESEZEDg4KQnf6x0fwy63BanI8vHE02R44qFKexyvBNjr@uA3rAm5cV1@8hexnIA8Tcx16Zet7buThb4wtqCXFctq1tTWmUNnptUx02HwK5E4nQ2nsz84LEeBzozFV@FHh9TuH9qAXDpNbBWNjLs6fqV6tiSK0hhwaS4dG6Sxr9m2e6Qfa2cYyC0gRCGwvmajnMbpucneCDHc9b0RCr7A7c9caFD8njFXkPbmvhehWNNr17NmU7xcE74xMrwmQPfUFAe4F2@9UUhSEfrKfLgell/@Xb0NfM79Lxn7szrmeiMTJ7E1YKgVPMgPH2Mb3S4aLLlNK6l9Vwbhhc47LVDpuc6s6nkzZwrZ4XilbNCFQ1exboBS3318OHzdLw30Gnt66TQ0CTa0rXxwMCFTmY5IIht5qOrqUNd4g431fSUjgpfk2cf7Un1iF3fcdfpO08WMIF8sMIEzH82vmP2cNvw2rIfuQ9dx4XZaAKMcvzU5GYHVg56rM@I2R7gi/VAn/61xTwjsBsmIS5tGBOzC@1rL10fMhdxwHeMqbFhKqK1QdL/Ite1fcWyu6b3ihb9Yu5NKu0qQvfMOekWmzsMH4PStNfjIjGux62MkZUdG3/iug6/E7fNwUN9eDVXgamAbh@@US7jQfyVdYG1@tlqVR@f8FMiZp/bxdhUV8/suja/X3EmybH4mQDDs0xfeYBmFiismGcSSF/@lTykdCUPWapGIMmeGD5t0q9XNZYg1fkXOAI0MryeizthgeOK0zkx2wjXsOnobD8/ONAFws@BYxm9WWCv9Dq07HF3TLeNCkOsNZ@aXXwrqEsGRabG/HJj8pWhwJpC7ERXZIMgZFc4qIss9QS0kfT109aKHrVKVWtCN@LUG7fL6bCO5Fhm742Bq2Yu0Wu5Nr0SD3VWHpFzw1p1bBjRKrJi0Mv2a0fS6tE1EGhsU5qOPND5lelVy9uhpZc1@yGzsYmbzKu7MBtFV9cfUWXd9fvpEXP1TCkwNwi8JDI9yOVDaX@j5Ing4f/x7Y8VmIQ7xXxo/QRY1/U7@ID8zHOCx4f0wCeuPx1Y88eAN74FsImdYLUKkAUefGSga2dTJaD1nJnNVx@GsXNX4z6pYxIZhJYkm9j11JRM50QiW3TzyzVy@Utfyj4aEJ6afSkwxYA7DdKD8P2vKFnwXLOBGueNeNhTVThh58V8cPxzHXFPQ84A8pY7lSY@PZWJ/@T@g8dH8sRX185P@yN8O@KSHLdi20Er52JLUq8ML7bfyY@j9S1/qtx@pkoHD@7LmGADvfmOhgQP3JlbeWxc9wwNySrGRi0IY83pegHx3tHDB5nlK5osdTDy3LGZjkcfPHuWxTdNPn62Njqe@y6MjoE735j9/qGqptd03@cO7Q5u4p5rStoE6cgEbRQ64z1uGuZa4arnTsz@0WJifgKTJ3Jw/wOLL26s5CPjxBriKGSVjYSigcoqcjGfjp3MBmXb9KLnpvY8tibILXv0UPhj43EUlBx0xdPXSw9X7fhflGJYLjiJ8MUyqbnLvTVuylgx/L8rYqqqbqLzM2MA7coKGxtrNcG6/WHbPfmArWQzUF6kKEiaQq@SrGvPkZekMbBuBW@4PB8EgrO78RjMVQCi4OLaAX9qOgvDkWgv6yrxogq58VDblUm@Zn7AhlR0wucE7aWv3eOLjtSzVI@c6WsKPvJiWQ4Obt@/LsPTgJZXp/ro0XP2xPDRDsrVCeMYmx@A8VIyeiXhuhUa4du4ndr3AJR2JbzhZP14rrJnhtd3ncX8@k04egcVp3aybxzBQh8lMm1rbq2bq3p8XevJ@mNG15XNX@JwFytycNw@TgDo/bf@harmcmT9CJ9qjnuvaZlwgLMUuowFmtSLRx3dj1hDD@UWGQLSa7XRB@Ycj6Pw1eB1Sv3a@a14xdxXSm@eTq6KK18Rl7@ivEtxGMh0OadeAbBwRRwryFH0A9c@HbnygeGZ/przx2sRuqoilSsqUolx58BgO20sBu7NIj6@uhA81vbWI3Pq5Scjt2vl19Zhf4B2LtlDtNd@OT44TmF4dLxl6AavfHD/@vJOZ@bagh4ab9ZHEKc5XhsFTNAczeiViMvRqxukXZB5TWdocROP7LY7PSTfFYpZ9Mbz@rMI1uTObLIZY@CN@FWMi@x8JeGnoDO7pz67ja/GLcX0Nbo/no9bH75JpmXRwiBaOr13tB/2rsfPFC1W4hKLz56sBOPLo9PHz2Jhnjmfb1J6pfkmHXJtzLLUR0f5lWJ3Gy9O1hBr8/tGIG4AP46eG@Ugzuw@fnaZJaD6NpqO7TDmY8NZrpiuNFjfndKbhmsjnyzmdIxybUuP@Cm2dXFeb03wimIPE7JlQdm@0umgOaZOZ1OvPDI/o70HEIPYlIslHGhgeMmc50chhpRl40B1j5fCzwq6zyYjy5mvjRpvykOnSFOv/PXDYJ89s91T9iCyKrSJPWjrgRsnprOJOa17WVGq6FdLYfoFkWpTu/APqASPTU1ye5OgdoFn4IGIq7gJ5n/aU@6Gnk@09LXpP34WJr8@7YHt4vp935qNr09MYDOZ6xN6V7C/iwCt65Ph90aOR67nXJ807E7V6m3zA5HY@uCU40XP/QAcuoPB9YkOfff6RA9n9tRCnWV90kfuzEYLAuviDr3h2vDGbqPVkqvypkg06O6PvPTmeDwX6c580IGsiHlGGaVX1nQlMOwz8TC0L286suOmL8D92GVfQUvya0jx5gPb6OO7m9KtbtjMcIuf3gheOjcd6p0s9GsH@RtrSJ4PGXSONb4y7dLk333PdbgvvWl6XJr/W1PSPcO2rmVo4YEH7ZqjDzih8Xh2ol/PtUBAuLu5zT5ZzJfq5mrtbW50Yl3cgQZEGfZ66fAjSHg0XdUxlhsNgDkn/s0LPxuYDONGNrhpA18OP0ySSjnQNdOrX4GL22lAy/CpbbSMvE02GSDt27dsK7CDABFiaFkhsPyABlQtZ2ai6Qb@bahpfRuKqdfVQoXt4WfXqkzNUZn4RckKt1MZFtZk22eBVYNqVT1nW3UmVkUW2JWIzM5z0@kAGI0@Q6WYdKyy7SnEbIc2ERh9BYi9ZbSUK/XQti74ZCVuHaYWWI0AnLbPntx/cvjsaP/o@bNmrn0eWJUIa@E4UFpou@aG3heh8gHdQEXkH1IgayY2FEdfKMIlYD@sF8Ovnq1Wrb5StWWlxD3Ms33mOIpChjUU6Rzwk0ReGsWioANBHHZYY2qgwKZKldu4IFMd0EYctEhlQqNVWW5dwRMD1J1tJ4i/@JFAisWPSVbxc5JYcGD7Hvrp0HX7QYm@ya6/whLv7t9/8PzpIQsRXPaaU6s/HdUrBf5pBG7sB9ppYNFJ4zpLBlmS0Fb1evJuEgiTlJOsSqZQ6LME0NEhWUgdNKIS5N5hqW2CDxRMRo2i/NevK@dJGV@aSUPaZIhUEoqFPk8dZWtrix1BJ2F3nt7/5PApQ/wP71AwkghBsCO0w/CnP@rzD/uEdtLCD2l6Y9JNyM6UELfFEhooWdpQQZrT2J1s/pwmfUiHLJVEX/CJPkEmCPSBJ@i3p2Rl9YL5yzRZpOOf/wysk4YFURcKPwaC@7NoaRS5nuVbaCcFcRig4c/Vzo5HOsnersz28Vuh@EVSg74yBajPnCk3rheY2EpAT5MjnpNl24Qs/yaVGEuY3N2Czt41QW1lvmPBxDmtslfQE3EPtMrt6EhSI3kpSwi6Si4JVZ1YwkuWQn2l5Snvf@WfKcMaA/cU3N8O3PPcbfD9UuAbgPuXufuFgh3tsmXRJS5xhNAgcVADjkhEf6R97BOpDrddtCQcGkANGSuzxtBMJ0R1TM5L4HcJ@PESTqr5CTQadDdoscBmES/P9NoptIhcVRTsUriUItP8b8758e0LlpGLhWJeVQBJ6SQESJ8yGaJdCg4wna7CMBFOrEn9Jajnu7u7TMT1VLNerPGWVbadF7r4MkJ0G9IKMN8Cck0GeSDLMgfENYJsMPtk1DRmRe6VVJPIuPouTEsUj9MX@p2AECJLAbE4jUz8NsYcv6Y7BS0jsPDdxe/Pxj5ztR0AklSYk8iVFoXA2s8jdwrdBwbp8kN23NoPvr7Ap0C0W@vzb0yTYW3sj/LlkbU0UhF@TysYazLyAA5Kz12cTeNtK36KIJ4hiKq4rvs2X7DWtOW0Fd43GXTTH6zpzA64f1EZbuizvN77l20apy5aJEZisVvPHBcXju9CZVhKUzRdUYvpZZXy@bVVCmoUFAPVQcNpb6E4YFPAMnqm9cqd@PsHh/c/fvzk2SW7vZQyeTEZ8P3GbqYlydlmO3Ik49VabZLbd5VnD2/fDRtiiXQxxo2B8Qc1Ua@qyXI/CEEu3y@8WLV1GF6s3WaMP@UWSC7iq2tXoUaZLuGh5r5AufSOj3SX3tS9WLhWXketQuEqlJbwlBjoA25m4RKqqfTZebMNWpuTSF7uCWsGwouEvIODAFwtf2dbwc5@uXJYsejr70f4PU0/Phb19WNR3NbRLCRaeZm6x0vDmUFALCJW37AYYJGCrIRJN46@x1xIX5p31fjX6bk9ybi1vBjCxdxVFI@BOgo/dI9cZGmcOrDLPAKNyra6QmilkNtnDs3IRqaZuYXBVFoIvrLEC07xV2fYvDqX6UBvKo3cjmBl2VWmnkN4aQEGNEp3T2ag2T1xJ/yrG3Rw644Zup66wH7vzPhCr8k@no0h3YAeT03aRAfOLUFmoGQyQpXLUsAlAkvP8wza0obymmjvOai4PO4XUvO0PDLnfWsIvD2VzgJHu6GqbRZZg8ZKk/VnJylSmy1b4cqh@BEaz4iT/QuZBJ8vETCahmw5fXOeSp4m09U2lI/hydNPT5JpcV1fItPkga3u/kUb5RH6JfVqTmJMg9EZGgBfxy0qlctcAsIuAua2MsNP/lUq8sgX6BOudZTcn029B@AEMSI1GBsTlpo53M6ozMibaqWcLBlglBrchrHDMhlSqOBBETKjnANy8fk7ZTgLllLq@JVfCPWdPj7eWBPWVGW5DW4qJM228VOcByBxoeXdtABKMGSpEtg6diFQMwAjPkhk3sEhD8ZDWniQtdY10fRlQtprdJEmVGvWuMlin1ZdlRzFSqUaNOgqV6ww6H2X2aGsANhLfC6U64G6gQkyoBmov7KQWDLyyxwvQeUmOCL3AttlgE4iZnc8NGnGANbSKnhv5OEvdejAWAH5oFp9fnS3U04rIotsoA09q4974fzrHZGKF3xvDYapspI0WeMa3UeYDa3NdriRNTR6epcGjHiBpSbiZAgsdofKsr/sm6p6Za8PMgatACnzOAEE74p3QnBoIThcU1oTt57Z//SnCRQ2UtuqetzxTjLJQq4GN7VWYAV2Y7slSdvNXP3WtgFa1PT1vAU6ubKTPzHvjAb9@0OlJYpMZ3lF2Tk7O0ve3XlivSiwotS3tOLr@eJcL@qv5@e6Wn59PFGLTfn1vC2W69njdqvZZk@efPau8y4tzk8Wr0XWSoGuefBYVPNiolphZ3tFPXFcwW@Qg3pzzN7AdTxg@E/uN/2Y20B3dwAqbFJkiVYLKK6KJVFRmsk2/JO6/xIurvg3G3JD3mu/e5duGsZ0vmCWZU38fh9@7ggkSC39jIG@fBM4Pc@gsBY9SYOCqzCeA7PbN4fD2aGxsGZ3p7fkklyWtdjqwu7Dr30aXLVPnz9n7Dl7/vzN0w1rEe1MJiVJTXLPL8RVO0YhgV8R/9Mfb51nz550dv/0G2PF3MLHY3x8@/whup@phRtbWzdu387ns5qmcfeTrz35@f39/fydbOFJs7CXl3Jbu3/yx1tbmrarKVtt31fbyebx8WeilsuL8p/@MNl58uSrvt/Q/4@vv2uoeCvB7YSVgE/ApTMVnHgvw09FGetDr8SbBPRyNbGgv04iDD/bYmpjr/Tfvvv4dWKaaGjKpx48p4nXiWI5wZ3gAJ8e@k4SjcQuJiueJxZKvV4HZ@m//XvI3/gY4GDMYhdujUIIq7hINKQ6ZXmbaBTBoWoalPt/ff3rMQw5m6iTGBdet1gTLjFf0sS9Nlw7dO0KaFtWyilKmM6Zjqamy9TyTfUmeizwwMMx8SMd5rSVUMt59vgWpHzazGQybbkjwSW/oEUiRVW1lqreBHYg3dip16Udxq3n6nrhJn4BIE1LWkMXZkzz5qcrV@LTv5drLZja3wPgp0KiuHXr5Z1GA2qnN/SdRoauYEjR6CqVRde9JbIse5kEZaTZfslqDzCqIebKmpjNZm91@NCYI9WkeThEEnjxeyIRheDgZRfCGjju2ywK57nY5bwsDnptusQhXn/2v/7Z9/7su/T3Pfr9JzTD6/StgbIDiU5gcDTgulWt9hoNseGJZy30N6BH5arlalnpnLdSO81G@ylTcx@9TRb05DOG84CKZbTSrSblb1CxjaB49DcSy@AGD2nEw4IInpgC4BlQiiVWqUbuiGqMXUgHk2zwwoLUPGm0JRSN6lJTLRbaEs/VvAWNI2qlithpJ6TtBfAdrd3QCtpjdqvBLzba9pmL2OhaMaxIgG9jWbdlzNLXiAclGmG2xjLNF00X4FQREs2m0jZpZmiEiN7aqm6Vq8WqpnQam6/aMgdelNQ0zSd@4iQRXTUW9MOQnomoZ8bCXsRbImoWFnZgtpL3mnTQVsAiYGTw//ilRRej5tKLqlgLXFpHZDXoH5ouacOOmFPFaLDRQj9cW/BH/3BFXrxvUUgQTEkuX1usqu5oulK4UTzUcKK95orjLcCEwXrdbvdNrwvih2F0jZ6hTo2ZMTcWxrQ76867096sx/iYYcvae7pbcMtu6JWlhF5QtxM3sUq6VtHK@AVHvVzWK5peUvVSUS/ltHJBL1f0Ul4vlQCgXtL0SiWvaXqxpBfLerGoFysQrkGaIqTREUKpoFd0IfGuucWecrbWZpnwamWuvZ7LcidwksPFnyS584SQ@Ae4Gqqmsh2Y@nJwA3mPnKCO45@qCiwBMtxZ@91O890OjPhGZpe4bbshBVjCQ@7camek8/MmuGu14H@3ETlrdHEXVK59nsnsvmiAaPOi0cwAyBcBSFliBFTuNFh7l6Ki0oLigvhk3k0W3Vu7bRCSpMxuc7fuHtBPpqEntQHy7gq2t25lZHDdAgCN7TZLZzLbkrSF024zmHwgbbuRCWsFgNopEETOzn7GH@iQwD7Od88b583d8/PdXfjfpft58ITQ891L//RYXhvSLOPbyHpaTaXRUloB@2mDX1YaGCIrLXA04AnpmrpWbuOEh@KL3P7H@S9nl/coBFFuy4C1kNhhOwm0MqsndoTEy/ef/8/4a73//PdQFGXwZ1aFxBkyCmUHFdkK12fhxpyHDnvILwfc@Au9GIIBjYcY6PCbg3tdivJSZlW@nZBSy8W0jDN6xx100HCNzF5C0hXOikyUiVq5KHYy6kJjiV2xWCIO@nOXrmQy@U9eapVSkq8BoeWVl77vP4xhucQTEte0nCqpbxv84yL8O1A/t@76Jz@36RISbyvMrAJ9UowTRkhAP0ooiiQ1hERjd4yv5uAujIQK70n9M@n5voQrNMaU9th6fPWhfv@wXqk0UP0xt5/QoNm5swN3Ff4Pt6AWrDWApK1BvTcG0bo10AtaCz9EkZC6r/HvwRv8Y0c9/Hv6Gv/Y0Rv8ezrFP/awi39Hr/Fvv4t/R2P8u/0a/x6@wb/nQ/xrfUnX1Zq4fUaEyagV9Xx7LhKBajBhNVpfmnqLKn1VTdT2NNBXgzWslJ6vpBOtL5nznjmZVoPFRnxPyuxNa0a9UuvWtSBpcMgbY2TLDz9bH6wtVjWWxlVQvVJwPQlPJMINAjJ6RXW95E@@841vJOv1pJSkD2LlIUzqYqIuJQIv5MxzTPBDw4AfNLfvJ2u3kl9q0vpCodJuYmQbIoREnW2r22rOzvVyalftgsNiOY/lRrmR2ldJD8uZLLfILVhu7Kp9cJnwlwOXlRuw3JDlnJwDySAWXNNOboquATyG8DcAQB78WXjYvavmegwKslESpW//qh3MmXvbaQlNlmTiSxMUaVmVc3LRauPnypriy5ctZaetVcpMxm4td5ovW8m22BLxExZaJc@6C3Or9VIEeSMn8u6PISzh@6Cd1xJKq6VwwgO5qCXPzzudw0d3Oh0FJ8LWQ/fx8v/x43Hce@X/@LH78LE7duH/8ePHMHjNRuZWBmaIW7fqMGMEj71Eo7bXqtK8E849CWV3r9XQJXQXMzCdaBiW@YLXEiI8G1stIXkKOtEpKFa1FKhXp7WTWu2UHJ9yLzg66MbA6P80cARPglCLlLNTuE4ILPnQefppK3Jxh/LpKQR9ykCpjP5Be417/x7@rX9c/w@fszRLNdvp1Nn5boquNP6l02fnZ@fBvZFOpQJPahf@MAD8mOXsvIFOSnQGrmYq3U6fn/MwuKfSuxxgA4rZbVDeZTqYmBJRkVQsv6X@fp9QdHC1kjUGjJAWDgo5GkcJscaM5aGhVmuey6WBzwVf58EtcOMtncxI1@jTrNvdptr@kx/SF5j20pSokK/V1B3GPVpeq9Xyoa9UrtXKoWc7lapcvhq5PbUIOlU@n07XauDZC8HmwAt5m@xdhtVZC@7tmzd5IWXt7dsQpp4vZnJ4WKtWC0sqQLGmb/QCpn92/zF9vAhYTSGBXw3jrCSVo0@f4USQFKvizZupvolvVPT39tM3b2qV3Nu3UchkAkHqSlCn07e8TgfD9bdvxY5Ih3wqBfDnym/fqrlKRk2mXS/1CL/LCkWlJJXd0BpUagWYvJYvQXSAQGF3t5hvNIp5CCmWk2k8MMBZPOCbFJM1MXFGdVDLJc4BxRoGR5oYDGQfJ9qz8wS1JssX0ingomkQQc8T@Ochw@UTXaGQruVzucTZucgTq5UKT51m@WKqnKkEf/WtNGuAmMX/UFbUM/md0s4tkLbxz5@vu5An187MunpePzOruGVwXgNRwXdBSEIDQObNm3oFSFTO1VpCp3Nn/2i/06nDXIaiGtwwkLi7gHaRvGS1dovaVS0XGDQgD5SSMCWwMlBZ0XYKahmpIlgDNOgFZBC4yrfFtgSNnngTKpxaWxAIGhSU1oeL9VmXDfFiQ9RAmcVsupjNeDzde70okcuvIDbyUl5SUsMQM7qEYNjpvE/CrP3kwf7B4VFW25VYQru7f5DVnj2/nVDRW1j6KVpH/9PD/TuPn0OGJw8O958dfnT/k8PnTyDcZ6fLK@TywX35jLvW@E/Zp8Ir741hmoY5M83O6Wx2@pq9sqyOBa1nz6BS7tBjvtmBukyMZb1q8OtZvvHqleFN6GLvf/Ct9z/4797/9nfe//a33v/2937y@fe@Bb8fwe87/Pmdf1cp4P0nn/@L33n/W78Ngf8Jfn8Ivx//5PNf/zr/kf@P4PdfYmF/FPxi6fhPAFi/9JPPv/vDn3z@y9@H378Kft@//PuVH6//fe@bm3@Y77u/c3Wa7/x7@P0uhxWm/c5v8TB8Xkr/WzzdL3///a/9B/7/J8EfOn/7/a/9Ed4Czz///p/8l/ff@I@aVv6Tf/v@m999/81vvP/mt99/859q73/936q5@O133n/v9//yD373L//gf6T/H9H9dz/k//33//mf/y9//r/9@R8Evx/D7z@A68d//h9hqPzN7/8A/7/7@3/zhz/A///pX//N7//q3/zSvyHHb3DH//2v/h2//9Wv/Oe//s1v/@WPv/7Xv/rjv/6N3//L//2X/89f/89/9d//3l/9s29g4G/8@C//8Jf@4hvf@otv/su/@MbnG@7fuvL@@QeEf/4PEPLheH4InA@p1xcN@fxnwufvQo1lKdBPoHf/4vtf/wXo4L/G2Ptv/QjflYXfhv8faSql@RH3/f/AoV2uM8bkwAW/X33/re8gif4HIBH8R/T6duRZieGeby89QNbfXJPpF3/y@b/8IfkSZrVBe1A4WZe1cmYHFJqdSiWYsIPtKcjyC6vQIgBBSd9GDrUS923kbe9/8PX3P/yn73/wG@9/8Es4W0v5SnY/K6nX7O1BwsIHpMOExQ9Jhwk/g/I7GVrUkzKfgW/rs0JZdxyn9tlnnwmdtwq@lH3rLfsM/thn4cV4FL60HUSFcRiOb3EzCG@@fNnGDeFYmKJy4IrGn0EUnteHkiTtRmZPUTUeZb5VtnkuVoMAvay3Yqgrg8FOFf4Y3KrVnbOstNcCoY@yngtmWCU1gLqlMNXI6ju6AQmVPE/Hqs6tXD5T2jEMUIEzCDdDMs9OKIMVdDbPBEXOg01jDIdE8x1yzhnfCZhT9FyY094y/JcYKzOdMYf/1wSWoYVyuvDjtaGTHEG@cF@anEIBisks9xlIKGRcKtvhIbTbTuXmKwxrMJ9n5qBtgwNKyEDUbZD76/UMZqxzFMHLK9MoM0Ilk6lDvTE3z5PtlBHE/DZBgZz1zFPW2anPecYMwmuE5MgIGPRUVDUxU67fgQLr8zsMYSFwAvvyZb1Rrs8bCO4dp05mnrlNOCGwembeeAf@OsGEfELizjtApVzPZBplLBAryZsn2@GNVKDKUd0zLBO0ATzxpYm9W4zdENWyyLdYtpBgPDXeM8vUmBCSQ3wrsxNUh/5DJ/12iOBbVFRQCuPxeyQT73ExGRMAXEmSZZnBD08x7LFbED3noDJULDwyHEKGegT1gCiA4UJURshQ@2bIA@Un6jtf@EJgWJnt7W0h0RB18bFMpFMU5h1X6Q0SPFSJqkyVicWKiMEmvU4T4gL5a1T@dhI3JZOMA2Y3Mvx369YOuwHVpOcyTGBSRnfzboJD2c1kRA3gN9yM8AL0HwH6KQF6K8jzOm2CZoRsljG5nsA49vjx4wAJCnhRFzLQzTVdRT/uxc1mswTkkOWsnM0GT5meFCAHDplig6e8jcQ99aypyTQtXwM1rcYwiMV1KhV0bQx89@4dtAqdUqveBy2XBQfWtHyZIiGA28Sy7UX43pWWrwh8CYCpxTxjKVpNhivN8AWjFHSktMDfbuBohFcqqZXLSUoJ9JdTO@EJxqKKHIC/yUWvSLNCacUL2MS9uCzI155xJz56hYrjlyoX0mHkwWN28Pjhw8NHR5N2mwn4gdzZ1OxMPLdn@n4K4/Yf3eEvwmiVYjrRbCJVjqoaciThsJrDjpq5f@fp/WdVxqkUtFmK6lGjTeyALhVVSEwmn@4mggNfIn7l1BWf4b26JEVKqwC3TCcaQqJnogoEnQ//4VcTHvrD2@6cpXJZUcyqRVRB07gZC3j8vDtjaIObG@yCQYivx8i7u0QBoXEmxTZ/MKDBnmoCd0gqOZheKYeOEneopSIm4IcqmS40nh0eAeijx0zVcrLQ@IzNZURNOhcadt02neF0tI2nE8VWTozVfruZy@KfputwV/PFrFootbe27DMJC2pRfzjDY6bn4D2TsMJfhosJXxbYlyEILigDz46yYC39/uNacHoS7WKm@BFKUS3ACE4LuB/AwQmT@FWDgbO6nSYktr72tSlrNA4f3ZHu3xUSwIhGLDxAKFl9eSRTh@jPPJNih4z1rU8s/NCt3Lf8iW0sYFQCNRLn5@cDgHT/LtMaGnl5jj7ez3sU0gX3@dwQEk61Wn@n5kvC0/1q9Z2uaQIECDsKnlDcgq5Cxzt2FP5X86EQXS8rwARVUYSHrusCdXShagqMDvO8y9XrEu@tel6lszwCfjvJmNeXu/JB2vmNZVo9x9NiDESw4dRjuTCuxOMCX1EgHxANjy/iUXShFoz73M2bOi7E6PlctOJCNWbn0Dbbel5HiuPrYe1EvhRsNYmi2E4Itjll/Tq4Ey248UVFTU2IDH3Ij/RyTkg0EzD6hGa7Wf9//6/dFNrzf7z/QJZmsy7MgYnFf0EwpqEnW/kT/j96BTuKu5OGnlN3lQk4DXDmdxUDnF1wFnaVLjgtcFZ2FQucs4au5naVWQNossvNijO0WlYXp@Ycv2LAw8SGb9oDGd@cq4tUgCbuBp/paIQZG/163@3N8KhSrS9bjmN6aGOEZ8jnxZrroMHberiRByw9fSYM66dkCUUw60MZbah5jmELfbnr9heyP13Y@A6a7Xr1JKgByTBiCd0E@RAXP/d0PV9tsrY8cSd7glYoZZpqDiZ2/KnlrJbdMvdKpWpf7tmm4e0VqoVyto@vtwXbrHuFXHUof/bwwb3pdPLUpHfe9vIVyIBWR9E@4F65WihAhxHFTJOKaTdzbZnzdmlrCxiiafQleOIurC9p5TZk7ltevZ5M7umqJqlVPVc@F5aEQ5pjDRsCZs1gzbJI97OAfVYd1wFOXc0aWeuMqFAdDAbnO2eZpUcwziTuA/qcS0a2exZ5a1IsXZXNspK1jIQQYwDkPgv2l6uiViiLtWZt6S8VxVr7XLg1NvuWga@6tXJnl3MVYUbjUBNQUIsJ51XPdafVrjlwPXOZUFeLYUKO0OUEefE8Kq6VwxLPLhdXjCWan12Gki@I51GuEC3h/BzozokNZA9sxjfoSHhTreTbh8C/ofvshubkMVnixQshsfP0E73RgKY@y5e0fCFf0PRisVDSYLKu5IugDOfUXDFX0DSAkq@UK6Vz6NeK8i5BX4tlB2dhf6/S93JSRpUbfG62WfrdI8s@K@sSxyOVrsGskHgnJG48/URrNDYr5ikQbj7RpEZdL1TApaNL0wXkbJomabqkq5Kq4/81Dg3/Pzy9Bv8a3iGXrglHaAbuEQgdIFI57AGak5q67MjFDwoO2W2ztyHFwcigA/sHnuv7f4c0tw3nmEfdsbjt9SjqnoFfVfXH1nS0IcXzyRgtyJnePxiEw3EXEER@yBPchptnu@66BCX2/MmGWj6MvnYCxOCfO4HkT@9/dO8o9jw63D@4JxTZ7ceP7lx4FIJEBfbg8O5R5C3x2DBrIQLx84cPHlz0Bo/84@dPBzPXw59w9/Hz/PIWBeH74EIertVEUTABCW7oJQEe5DHQkAul0KEK@BbRzXyF3QycheLSmUPnp/xld8uP3mrhdg@qwlH4BrzBkNV2TdbjhgJxGYWM@AYqllqqCMKEOe4pK@VY37Vtw2PuYLAFgSMD3@Y1UXGwbeyJWPSp69n9U6tvbgkP8cXhCuhfA0JCuAdAxrMe2aABURBNwsO05jDcmOzaM5PNJmxjIDwwCJ2eNRzBJHzqhgmErmEw@H3RC/Kb8Wt6dcCUl0Fhl2Lsy8kFULbLonggiveMqdGpeWbpRa5afeLBZGz4Q7NxOIf@CqPH8BbZclYXp@JdVnVe7GhD3Oay3Qnqef6kCeoOKKp7rb/6zR/97R//6rCutXIHuQIu0O3uPXyQ1xYGl4NVpdatvwPledx923jB9vIuzNK3GKtu7WmFKrA@0BEYqQGBqiCTeqlVyoVyRdfK2XKlnC@oxUIhq2pZUOVLFVC5cmpZLZYLFTVbzldATMlXILYAeh5XNJRQs1B2qgDW6dmzvrlLGqo8AlWUb1SzNykjzRJG5J8x0YQ8ooCrB1OynLBj1WGGZWqO6SUGEA3WY4m7dw9yd@@K4m304EGfg5wo9tFTKOdypduiaFLMQRlFLtHlecpoiFecck8udxvaYMYB4DdsRHGEnsMirr@KooWeg/27d7GcAXo0zA/JjnkM99ihpwTJHPSA/kMAXkfQINk@LydPiB6iB4vEmLs85gDiRPGjEB2MecqTcQD3wpru74vife7Z38eYA6p2gSP6FfTs0yWKHnhgaIjiEBxDDwalKHbBiQNEFHvg6i0MCBuDCz9z4kwNUVxw8iCBRHFOqY3esSh2wnAs5pMAmwJSt0oeldf6Fnkq@CeKWog0JtMjjy6K@ciTh7rdu/eJMZr2zSG/Fh5/9qCm9@7phjWfHd7tfvRRdzjseov9w4@eYtTBwT0QVxYzrzvsBhm7HbhcyHVwTzOOx4uLF9T6fqdTNey1UV/pdPKGcyGqs@iYiCHkeg2YBdcQCxp3DiDq4F7nlrHuoAEB7CBvGMOzi9ftMTxvG10eFV4URc95tyvWsPsrSisloEKBJwZwOB4Dr3WyY6PnuTX0z@ssl0WRZtEs5to1imBjUAxytXOMH6TwbuCiXfps0ZzXc@36vF4KjggOUmJrrhUsMbs13lMrheqWsadq@cy8isZb3EGSJSV1j6XUmztvWOpRek8DJWFLbO3tSWJTbe8VSy92ZtDweNvT1HI1n9NYmnv1UhXy5JI5xvCWbpbae6VCdZm5VMoYilYtlUBsA/pMYfLv4jJZh6VSp6ZxnE4j6rQWA/WhirMFVdqqDVLz7LzOkWSLdG1eV2vc1j/LXYCWSvXxwzKzHtoTZxzoEADO93JVPKySEtVKWQQcFCWVTkc8UAHXcmHr068eHR8dfUYSYiNYKHrimcjMaoH3o3sH8v3HoQ8/CiPfRcnV9eQDZGIrMVyEDYOOQGeR78GcC/pfGIbvzHquLR/SQU8Qf8OI0C6dHBhol4/urcB5NnJPeclocqRGVn6dnsnwmzlWnxn1BriMPksRVsxIn9Js32k06p36mKxyQBXDXF9h9EGZJZj7Psc9MoRC2c/wPdIgolPPncNMM0/MAU6nziT15djtv9QyvVofP5Vzu34bM9c68OzWzLrpea4ngvYt1gZ7Tn3m@MbAfGJ6aOLn/uNtkD3w5dLUgJnpbdY6xNQHqNmcSw2POUvMHs3GKUNqdNOrQbhcGgUgcVJfDSt9Ru87d@qieF4b1FnqBSR9DX5vm6X68u30Xr4GdLrNOmkIyr0cvBwwjRXzNdJMUggLRhbRB@ttsHS98RV4cNjH1SpgEzT0MUDFwgCw1acISD2xzmu9us1SEpuzNBEpXxvWm5j9Ld52JVFsS1LzbVtoSNKnQgOGb22RMOr@rEtfWWO5rqrlirU5hKmlfG0EzWu8mNe8@mTmmTUbvMHaKX@126gBUYF2AObN29T7X/h6elcq1HlYjUC9RVmhI3fq85qDdpuhY9T1OkRkmvlcFnR@uJWyIAJoxaxazOrZfFYqYSjM/9lCFgJBJQKJJGWnRMbEbG6ek9WsaqrZVO6l1X@Zzh6nQMohorF0duoeOrMxgxBoKuyb5IUnkCej7digqvVdZuxK1FmBa9SwYkD1EZtY2RGCemoaNuVIpyWm76Ts7RSm2T6aTQ6b7Wr1cD75KkSlpNd7xUwpl3mTTtdSW@m6b74WGjWhgQyGaj3Zgp4bLCszfzZuQiuDSy1p1Wazi1Us5bJ6TofaWZ23w12xIbazua2iCk10zohtMM434iutKAAtwyYdFNVtE5pOrWg1QaZlT72sSRWlsFPI8aVXnlOYBAwOKclSLTE0Y5BKJktaMplO1nA/aUsM9gOApxE/SwKDTd5U90SQzcSqWNEwwZI50pvquRA7kM7OBRQjWR404TPh/Ox8tyF8SXiG7x/vai/wr/Ti4f5j/PsSBFXAW37x8Pnj54/vCkyhs8FyJ1Hbqsm1Tg08kty4JSSqjAEnbQU21pQtxr7oqePMbuMFf7bwhReAK9C3GJqsTacBTQvVPPYJ2u/YY0mog@GNm5qmt5taCaZC4KZhUk1Ta4BFJ4Fv1MgNaIz5GeC3m2ngq69fYYuFkZHCtYGb1cYws53TFomTjlis6PzNzYaaO2ZbyZs7DKQbiSVOjrca2k4m@aSqZ5J3kno@cZJqbTcy6iKpsJ2MthjgoQbcHFeSkE4zd27oO8nnmWp5mK2qGbxrcK8mmbSVuNXJ3kpXfIGahCUuLFbs1/eHT/fDQ5T7B42ytghe2U286IjlUoBiaxtIpmVerOZuwPz7AncnWgK@j5FMnCVZInkOf0LiFr0WrPHXglkiejEYDxUEW216vsjSiUo68JUqCT8V7XN9KXkrkcTtpKrvv0tQlwrftfzKSw16c8JxwwDQ/nBpDmbbQgF3UhLKy4n/Na2sP7z/2Lnj3TWFRGvr7ZaLO2CsFqH/zvn4q4xNgMBJ1qon5vV88HKD2mhI6q6GhhBLrAoTykAtSrm3DT5kGhRR1CDm/S98Pz/fBQWJaTkV/JpWyGiNhroDkkpi8v7z30OTVmeHn@w/YEncDfnbP/6hVvrbP/7XdAYyeU47JJpeSkBKdKrFUuLsbHJ2dg4Xjysk2olLRz/aQB9FNSqlHRlqo5QNcHSUBKcjSFQlNZ3wpURw1rVYkFIpVdHSO3o5l4aYt4HJupSWK4M33E6kILFYENOJw6dWQVNv7e5Bzfb0vFbbgrZUo1e8WfS3a/oV1DUfvnzLGHh6jf5waGnkUhRWfSftvmPSLnuHO3nvpC32st7Aoysqvhge7l/t4AunuD2cbGSUnSQDTYw1mue183aGNsBIp32x47Qu0KG1ha8zrQbtOPBn7vj0Z5rkpQAfvKHP3Hnli6mdtKL0@@LlFbxdkxUa0FV2FMByJ9zO4n@S1Eq//4Vf17Ti3/7xr7ztvO18poEWW6kUVS3x05/uzpyZb/YbP4WMVxgwCjVRkj/R0hA6Ig2WcevQVpArcsg9UJ5nDkrrPH2oz6IGy0C0sYaO2Sd9VjhBcYxatMNtaPZTlGwH7ZtkSdonm3XpmiCEkjCX5r1hL0sw2A6aNG@208KZ8GWMgtmegUZQE768BAUBY5jf3V7Ht2fehF4DS1E@tZ1lNyELlPBltE@6RXZZgqlCAp6p7FzOylH2iWokurGx6fto7RRmOeHLkCX47oO9YBMDTQhhSsuBuUnGJIQnRfSbUHYbyrZ5hg6Fpqj2PEGWcex4JgeEfOHLIK0QFSwQYpi1CwlqwE6@DASAOqQCwFab7TI9zc6sTKa2NKV6jq@L4GtRRmi@RMBsCK2P5nLCzDVMB0GgXOCXxrFfBC0MMmQsMATCYfBDH3VQTzA7@VAuJPtCHwwKYJEtvxRVjd28ucSqXrf6aUY1QvjH1gRX4qgdnPW4ArBQz7vRr4pZhkZqa2Fo1O2A4hlCF3qdxK3T1mJZmYjec0GA/w/utNgjLzQVRdSwAkF78VHRA5JBZiQ7b8Me260zVSulWYR8D3DvEVJkRCJSXlvzG7L2WRh5Dhj@NBF@xw@Y1VF8dTPotxft1zCQ5Wf4ETW0YsiZQWB3htspRKZ3fxrmjnJBVSybUg8sD/QoOo0SmkhN6Woasy1NyhIe9EKHlmf4XkUhjQ/KhakZPA009RmUs0UmynouNKg/cR2yDUq2y/ClFugRwKMCs4oc7Zlzih/dDNqGMscx8smkIvZ8xJhsnbpoBIry4umOrgcad0ibLDOHMuuN@0yrsBR1NDL/6ETg0pSJEO6COI407trmGFB6Zpr0MqZfVZQhiGizLtnAfGhBvxrdtWDmcXzlDiewcmodW8oRWr@X3AG@s8ktCiVQqsPhx4@HBPYmbdc9ZrZ1bPJF69SKPSafgUICMnUWKLv8AWGreKRJ07O4TKJmeSr4leBR4s5yNpZ3K7VIX37q6laqgy36liYfC1rFNk8MJ0Zfut4KgSbuL/zQohvZJQO/HLFcM7DlVE@ilZbISJkQ2Kark1k0GTdDJikxIYY23dApTDzzhKFOLeAcA0yzF1pHwlEMtf0yTQA09mBkoanXqVdFm16AiddP9WDoBQzeYTeYrgmYkBvcC4zjAQxs@voqdIiDrFgPf9qHhpFpBwD5CozOcR/i0JpM0P0wf9i70U1meJfdm20F4HDSobLqjA@L0FOIeXB0YH@mqm9BZBEwXIPJVkrMANiMmBY56Cj/xey8twvES6rsMqQsQwgBqQEKiQoGshy05Rn7OqYAEbcNn39CKTAEe3p6KpN14plnyaaPX4z0XcewlcnQAknYVabmeKKYPgxdz@opkxDu0iXxD8XKk9Fkb47ybL1yc8GfgjDw68E5r1Ry4CdxcjzBDyIOx2TJEE0I@tSh7lr0MdVeKjh2xvuf1s6ehf2viv1PKifPEQhjCGaeXWR7WQCW7faOs4PTfi2IOKEBCcChFc0wEG2Ge6Fn7IcuazKIUrhT5KNRVNc@pj1lgCTy9eRl0byGYcpF6A38E2sOmRzzlO17nrFIUXwaU2MHTi1I7GELmPYpBpz4eYkzbsDamjcX7ZXs8yg7TGrRiQoPzRQKZ1cD5dbMMX7O4@cQP@fx82WhYbHNeZuLZBh0jtXBXo/WbcOUCGYRpjnnlr@XMQQZ5HCmchCYcrESdg6/Xp1yh/TmPmjHetgxoE9MgOBmSmm@aDVbbcc3T3faGWUInV0kQkCLA@hmm2h62o/cSH37xJ64/kqQg0aNYVYK8Mag3ijoDbyvYB2jBqKOwelloR3a4Tg4@sEFgqDCAAHlMIhE0WB/mrLStch8PkVCx2mKSxpzxJoBMm2SvoKoIAzEJU56Ttg4oHYMEIZHVQI0IYaFI4d/HzjkDp96LqQJ00r0SdMx2kNMtpNAyQtDhfOaGjVSDCtJCtEEsqO4Wr9YlTAemqJ5ISpWzfOg/ePob31h9AcwLtZjTx2WTxg1IT5U8FAriBDBcCGqskY91q6AgbJj2KYHM9chl0@D2RqK2VFCNYOXg1XwT61pb5SKNX4vzduHXuoVHbEadYVFvQ5VXNT5sOTjIiQpJ3iUzQ@yLcKOEOTnDARg5P6f7r5tvY0cSfNafAqYkkuZVvIkW7JNmSpTEmWzy5Y8OtjtlVWsFJmUskyRLCZ1YNnub3Yv9gV27/cR9lXmHeZqn6I3/gggE8mT5Kqe6f22ui1mJoBAIBAIBIBAxNRigS52axe7rVREcKjbGcVuLCRvGclbKSK5b2cgeaqL0eqpbqYXdM8paaewus0SvJJMo6QG9bMq8q8DnM//Cl@tOLTQdSYyh7lA8xBUbPBZ83Rq7ScW0pbQGgMARpwAQFqIf9UZljPjAq@Ui99iGSWkNDJK3jQbiKwgBmMRvCH@zJ2YyXgNTAp/doXnARq72ZWTTLbEG8/4X1H@ZT3z0fwrTX4spnOW0h@L3tj//kM@noKy1gC1tI9S8QkEMlYyx13tCNjWORZV9YoWOKTVnd30lDNF2abvhStdtHDW6Z0VLn3Y2SAAuXzN90euWT/g6Ea97PeG/rD35ElZFk0hs920@mXNEJ53e4hbaMU0IF2v1Qui7vKQOrXZO@@GUeApuJv9HOhlR6BjsGRsPVk/9qJMRpt8yTIWoIWvoOo2GmE3HDYaDiwp3XJsfc@GlWDP5eUM1r/0ZJUn8aSB7ved3tmvQXPo3g0TATp0saOw@dnZ7@tEeDKpKpJhTdL/KfWCNBgV9ZKVIzv/hyp9NnQ4Ws1F77J3TlrfVZTH/mtmDHw9gQ2E/H6fcfGUjyVt2QrTwqPEaXq@q4v@9N1F1U@rju/G5VfTAFLE8NRgnMag7GBKdY2Z1UkxU9/h9@N7aON7OB9fXoWP4yxL84okfl/Vj50EAmVM0Hh8NxpoOsmt1gQ6KVTiz9CrpMC9UWyxHVsLmFYpa1Vnz7eJP7z4LaK3GPH3s@g/vwNN8dp9u8@nYa8ORyRvLmETKl6IInMC61D2ugvZM1ldzNo796yL8iLK9y5UCFJjWXB14becBibigkXxxrEBfAfPw3Rsgu/ZnqwiiVNwGlx76vPq7C7aabSCjj8KWo7O6VlwTYsPaMHG8up@DYegY6HXk7WeQ3OXG6fSNA6iS6byDJbxvWvXnc1WkiWMuYd3yhnD@mz6IX1CNGOLryK71bQOWF5exHbsdYjtT8RDk9AYHYkzquWozD/Sk3BMcjdBiA4ye5a8pFp3nvg8cOIm3WNGiPPm002G53oDES7HJvvw@0h0d0upc61CFdPLmXRQqOk9Hs7rcYsrDE/KcdP9WPIuprs3z1msJsASEbb9fVPIBGSYjTSbjg1RvsztsV53QibgG@/TdWfMKo0pAjUuyZJuGPJym/ULN4OVcZ1@seH0nn4B8DwYNoShTNuwp6VDdytOufT7ltaiv5CSTlAsKgrJNRpWrox5puxfvsV1NmfW2Zyos5mqMx4B6SqtTJlmqkrdC@ieeV3QCdrDGdIZSVg70888sU3/dXv@ALsVX5bD5XLoqeXr5TIJ5OVguVxzSCgvt5bLO/wQLZcP@eHzcvknekjG1vLX5bIZFsgwoFd@eInvWoTjvblc3nbcb5mh/zmITL355XLcp5TnR3llihAp0G7SGnHE1u3pZg4HAU1srFR6ChwTeVg@8T6Mx/@K9H8J88YBoJCIPc5HnFmtqFJq0rBmDKmHpg0TYGTKSC7r2by2v8tmV3EWVLNCazy7DIMnNXxxOS2MBDGk8okG/RKCkJvl6Rgpaya7Jzq6duJQ7uR0/RKPk/WBlsPpJ5T5NKmEY/vp8qa/0iCkA@@HJwrPwnMCHVMdY4QzWXcKWiDqL8tzGoW@TuOie9/uId7rTmcibHMmi/QSg7VkOulwfDjHEU17/TSTcCpuA4R2Gd6Uk0EJ7h0rxlJBj8wZyfxZtwyCwR787rzmWOWAWkoEIfGkeCqjLJ4XWBYjKZF1lqYqg49QsGQOjfCg@ZnjJu7oR84n4sbjuWLWNGTKSpUsudJikgrn4Wjtyh9K7fHitQb3a9@3fDUlb7HX4gCAVTKuReRr7zv0957o70ahNkQYq2CaYj19Kp1Ur@fOsmOYd5JqJzsQiZ7acacqR3ENCclpdWBp5vN4bULFh8mHKPlSaQx9TNs3ZIvXBHfQbXxtIbCgJQyu0x8/r9LHz6uzCTWpkXSu80ZpyaMmDUcaHmOaNG0@rtLwaV2MFN7f9jvf3cGDdAfbnQd43IDBGMlllA@uumzlkoxtEtvyBSK1VFYiyPm4NO7m5COJez66jY9t6cN@42Bnf@/NR5p0nz596uo5epTgh1GLvdZ4HhfIbMMdzwdTli2rHoKb4bAb2/HRRW8wfPCpm52QJSKsSRnwqRbDfnqMu1qWWfJ8bOxSOclrUVTD@pwMAz8llaDq@JiyQ03XIREkGDqPfA3EqLdEb49Xay6H8Wo0uv4ljPkxfTUaMF5qNPQshq4xJ@Lu3xcfFK6iQeEs7BYkBt1NJsOOSNTOvvrwunqkjl7X1O7x9k/q4/6x@lDdO4KjiHfHW2/q24r@1fYOayqTMsFDvE4sKImuO0Ez4CjQq8XiE8WQt3v9kcgdZ9uV74f@pXrdawY4pnoR@ZcvL@Ql3w2Gm1KqRsvREfYwQ47PehkOYW/BAUVpGQvlpsU3GHHtQFHeM1rTXmLNe9lrhe2Q8maw9u2HQWQuvalOSD1I8tZc/PZESULsUDYd4pjAsMC6oeI@5cfZDYHxxf4KJEYOCTbayitNuPi/76bgUe3g7aGCd5Lt/b2d@lF9f@9Q7e4f0Ou7j/W9V0TP@uHRQX3rGEmc8e3@Tn23vl3lD4JAMa/gNuTXq2g4F4U8sjNVmp9x8p3vU/fHb@ldb2jw6sbnu5yRWr7qQvqEfif8PWgtb2SuIqgvuD/KRwXKWaoevHpPc74KfsMJpzkKZvuD7HHE8WyXiuoF10aDZZPG24YerjTt5Uoun0dcjhRCWgUb7CTE4WdPGeBsxNMKA5Xdho0K9r7FlwiPZQOaKnpAsAHKGKxUFIeiW172XjDITaqt2enBea3UJkaE@gVFXxpTk40MU0zbygAorlXUu9gPKm3EH4jv6cOqrnY4kAzqcfxBMqgn8gGqaB22I2pN57ga7l9BPKt1@fDrZX@Xj4XV0/jDls@r2GcaJ@k37lJfxaE84VmlwwEHZZeHgyKLSx0UiTg/gvF1OjIwAgkDSzJRjhLZto1yZknYtHHUoM3eJLw6UokbYCfkt4eRcipuXh3BOCjohhLq8bzjd8UEKjHdYd5Tz@Afq6KviodxiES@qNLvMQMiPGsaj7jcjtYKg/uWo5JbEzX62kaSwxQbE7S7ENiaQOCPgCFAudRKp8kzFV@vBZheW7OyE/WII7Fv@zc7P7Fz66oZpApoqy3n1/D3311NZC@1TjJ2iowdddHvwYDUSj7KbPcGNMZZrHJQOUjB5kWvPwylD510C/jEiac5yo2JjWr7pbKZqg10GK@x2@talZ4RF8@o9YyY8j61MsfL2XksvpJo48T5NAmL3R3Q8c9614F1dubhEOkmwPYLKcJ8Vo7Nz9GQMRH9M5PIjr8pBCl@Vtnc2fqU@9svHiIVi1iQQOHG6BD/iDFRFw0PPudjg8UB9C490kyEyejqDKW1DZ6WlhjlBhitAy9CWte9bGzEaWJuPPkdl3jGv/PHr18rUioHyaSjy0cXTiLdPHViqvS4zKnSJiCW7CRkSdY75ovHMGN5/RIXd9AL8MrUhRzBun0sfqMWIaZ1Z1dtkiw6jLbu7hi@qzbZosIokuJDwu6Pws/OVmVl0y0kBiXKIqdjRLRnIJdc1zJL4flqAtzOfHAkv@8P7tlc7GR6@C5oO3OhfRduuZXZsGRasmDdH@zf5oCVye0PgaW2e7MByyQ5CS3m9Jg5vaXF2Jp2fo2/TPQdjz0Cg7kXOygxUKu2qy4fURtX8I4UcG0wiUJ0eLRTOzhQWVmfUFmSe1gytLQYBOwH6l1ibRt2WdjlY6UpXizHypP5krJoM//NG8xTiTdDVGgdxNP0iIVFfA@HFnS3IvX0zMIqBFvfs0A0lEtj98XIoOhEA/5Ga0BCNuk0q4GZqc1clMknjGwjcE03T3Rj24afLaxl7kZw6sHIBmTbBPnnuFkyvf8@iH5cNvWIggVvTGhwizRpmm9onXBIFfcpYz6f7sE53WK6FEb2omAvGtrB8KuY1rD/PEMxI4kSLrqwJda1cqxRE/14yag5bJCIacCHpadOFItmSjAinr@8sDvUTSY9Jz0FkZKJcMUvba6g4qff9BTG1IjnyUqskNtjbYmxOTFYnmJ3VsPemJ3pIWyh18fFw3hVJG3nVpX7x1Qls0SqJkPzqY0xiQR5fW3t8V2wx1thiuf@LGyZQ8bl5/CyT@v7BGQ0inh7nzi3vueZ9IQB5pBOTOvNgBkrSKrOlDkl1XaejGz8CBfZFyJkEE4BEaDHa3XV7Rhu06HLjGRD5ywTbbCGcNxQGTUT1P82vzoI5Dvre/D99clgQyaYDn6DVf7b3iAKklt5lmMZ6xNu4Ke/BYNBl7PJfaZLQHH4GtPcy3Z8204MXqVVSOTzNrslbX07ScxuPbPXwJXw9mIeQd@xu7cxvr2XK23YTd2tv6mpR@yLtJ3ai8wOsq4lex6E3XkIsAzmfQlMH3yH72FUpn@Eg2dAEpn4Np/DtHHvxI0pQlrzCQfY0mahWraWxnu/HTX9LlyReNmHkcp6P1BB3oWt7e@603bWixup8oRc1O86VMrL5vJZLkrfsKELSGkQ0pv4bk1YuKlhLCVxvea8B/soHGwFt7J7xpaTfqH0rLj@PMOt63pD7/Lk@an3qFnJKpp8/e5ldDW4aX0@711ct1VH9X89u22Ofv9NqbUn8EWuVn8QX9Ol9UqBvfU@VXBT/rzInKsR/JH9ZiMIeV6iMyu1rJJ1@MYD5fIDL5rLuCExxqXq0aXhQlyxG1YuT9ZPK91KcePypHu6gUt@w5XKcKW04uDDDzSLkoyRk/mT4SnmVHvXNeheK7hd5di/@mqI4qsh9OWtPwh7b6p7r1K7cVAAsAWmbb15Q10Cvi/Amg13T/Ld4MbR22SeAsdmoCBlFvhWUAmX3Xk/GdsxrZAwo17xSJuNbvnvyM0sFPNX/WGPU4yfSLCW@hp@zSyYa0xF3lGgLCeh8SaJ@wUEJ8nj4GBIvo7EijpXEnWthLuTrgXiBCVZHGY/ZbO4UwhE9V2uk9NMlA/85gWQ6JBa/ZWLqRcvFN6I1aI87@LBlMMf8IWJ4ikecQBCP30@bUAVrLlHfO0jQ83HewkP8oX3qIZ8T4YN5DOsKSIF5t/qC99v4vIviABC@AXRufJ6i1NrXqRIyt1B3lyAD7b0wh/HDLhWKZ2ygMYCttRXSYCzpTjTCNVqMtH3hRuQU2hF/@kW5Er8NtGMOL8r2ZkkfE6t3yLQkruUkzbx00mKOVaxnClmMlukWLiTGtjpouXR24CG1UhtB50OIS20WEjIgUe@36vrX4nrj05Q52mMvKTnJtJzqfS8pAtSSa48TfBJprKdKbv4Jcn3TWWTbN5EXRXFykueerqZJ5UkybsxL2@UH/YaYZJ5M@5K4co44UUqIWel/Dyl9yXlQapMzOBx@omka/5e1T0fY5nK@zJdP34zuoMCNp7VtiZjXJrvhp0fZdKKU8BmWaKmUlKcI5MqM6gq@g6mFiekwWGfn4ftZiWBslIyEofHTHbzxctsXisZPzrjaMgtxomBNWWMWFTiOleYcLd8YZHq4eQHFgiGCUZTZuRumsIjXXhkgUWuB6ZauQU5McCpaeNDvIJ7kV/xxwz2NHIm3@L0xAXB/FYaL7eb0wRiofsgO51MaWmC6yLyUTdqziyS1D0ahzhdSOxZu8BxnYHcwW5jG/xBLCdsQWEkxQTd4xRN6SRDybDvrC5E4rfM3wuPMq980rH7neBWVbHM8PkWViZ1wX0YRMMI3qfYMU501e93cOrICt8NX6HW4RNW13DckkC0ZvZ8pg7LHsnv4UlfSKdCebUPyDcwEEkSoqvzc1wmww3Y3g1EK3ZcwmE@U@2OZEODxszjVblmHig432AB3AnPbSSk52T0gNJR328G@QzpaBFpPxlpajvUAX15Px33RuDkjKa0cibzL1dh8/P2K5znPi0VH5cskl3r4@Bi/vGT5IIVEckkrMJt4VrpSSZjnQ035Ww4B4CeeoOJ/j3xZnAddLtBpkozBmeMSGmNgsF10MpnMgdBfAgMuGBlnEziHnbvatCUzR1SunxiRtwSjjw5DiMOwy/mZzkubvJZmZfBoVVy2kxdfR22QEBz46Tdw@kwH1jATYDQA4UugyER5ZGr0ijx2bPGhXWXS2xEETXg58Q6m4jJ0O0Nwyb1DO9kZToESo5Bksq6rTFMqL5mx8fl4Pw0BHA9JqGAQcAcJc3DIaMPzb8LB6UbZs7YfdMzBZJ@PR4rNNyDQUjSNyEw9woXs3CnDj56XT9Uh/u7Rx@qBzVFz@8O9t/Xd2o7ausjn3HjoJwdBKvX@29IusSn6XJqvk8fstVDKpnlhEx176Oq/fXdQe3wUO0fqPrbd2/qBI3AH1T3juq1Q0/V97bfHO/w6TtBUHv7R@pN/W39iLId7XtcqymWScqp/V31tnaw/Zpeq1v1N/Wjj1zjbv1oD5XhVL@q3lUPjurbx2@qB@rd8cG7/cOaQsMyO/XD7TfV@tvaTp7qpzpV7X1t70gdvq6@eTPW0P0Pe7UDxUYCViu3aoRldYuWsKiJ27lTP6htH6FBydM2EY8QfOOpw3e17Toean@tUXOqBx89DfSw9i/HlIkS1U71bfUVNS7j3EEV6pft44Ma3CaBEofHW4dH9aPjo5p6tb@/w7Q@rB28r2/XDjdU5s3@IRPs@LDmKcT65KoJBlGL0ul56/iwznSr7x3RnHH8DvYOLnXyByIMYVmlojtMYJhBoLVEpP2Dj4AKOnAHeOrD6xp9PwBNmVpVUAEWFdtHdjaqkIh4ZDdT7dVevam/qu1t15C8DzAf6oc1lzqsfogMdRhkfCTWoUqPudXoJ8JLHolZM4ZzPe5OVd9V1Z33dWCucxMHHNY1tzDZtl9rmufhINjaRAl72DPwL@2Nlfbkp@sAPjAnd2Sm79HEHpO293dqNCNrJ1fZJOGYZp1nY66U7DSaaeJEek25rGkFZ1fnjbDb7uGOaVxMNj4uo3MPgaVcBNn5lJkT103vr3CBxcVG4321QQvdw0bD9e5TMoXGXSX0Nvi8XK5uI6JDYOWNjZ9yWej@IkWozR/0QScb6uEAAjmF@j@I6Zt/GbiqUGgFuhgu7wOw2TqK5NjkAkcpJBr5siOiAyVV8s4Ev4eaHbigY8Dnmw3sk8IykjP1IvrT/Zq8yORgfSDpLNtdhQIWsYxG@HtgqpFK2CUC/9EeCcI2V5mPguDzuVO0q8OaP3/e67Uc1zVlOO@Q1oHnjntH8bPgfKx4brw8I8vHzjqwQmTW3azCxOfPmmRK90t@wC1z8Kcx5B/XYCM@H7BrylXxZrXetHR@kOKwSPKUdm2B6xXcydD53lb/Wv@A1Vxx9cnG2PfX8XcZW7AXhL9cmvBOuNwp/7w@lQw0wNgXB5Ek1B4yCgWrjLE3iTPfUMYLZLoJW7D8obn6IuB5nUhCiuyV37HrxGw8CG9t7EkOvzqovt063t0l0Qlsnzxbe7q@kYndbv3Vk9@PqIcd2rLXsT7N46SncZI1SrZJ8eGRYrkXT9ifGbhQQEY4ljedxh/h5yG220hbMkGQobkRQmV1YaKXDUCHrGIHHA8yhl@njkzNAE6qqS5ac@nfsorvk67EPKCNWToj7rVb/AHsePibIR43SDOQZjF28UucS6sLlnvZXWMqyosbdtyDLPms4WNx4xbTgLe62H4Wt2v5TfO21YuRmDJivHK3c0lC4sE4FsrYVXRlZL9jPyN6A5i9h9GXv2p@o8eP2sEdu7vzo2F1eEhk3I1LYp862YzWjT7RkE8R6ANO1UxNLxR2@V2NFI89vZ0cOwaxRgOjgrA1sPFNA96I/YiMV8kWsC@XXfVFOBXOOwBnQ3OsfifOndYcDWXD@A/R78YrhRJYsZMTodpNXEfGZPkY@7Ew5EyR6U/Rg@H/E2kyBf4LWnES9IRalhPAe1GSoQqtaPnKRAlvzEGDdbqRUNP@9DEB883umIu4Yfr05lbu1xAJdO@MzIeP7Paw7UwhAJgcGxv2@I1N0i58Wjq9zLq6OM5Jus3LvqP0XGGmigm4ufVTj9Uuz5yt4MVVruw1WRW@oaLqpSzcznjU05JpbCmvHkZZAeca/x@FR7wBEg945tILsVod56yiHmVGDmhXS9aE04o9JpFa@m3mqd0jZbnITMl@ffJlCEWgN4HPZDs54klPiXlu2uMiz8TqiL3gwW05lsmYfLTLujM2xOwEgPOwxZshCIoyvMEE0RHo7Kovgaach2wogkoSq8PEzyDErZsn0vK0ehNjzzuT4NAY@@Ou@MwPZFfL5MiLgw@NoX1dPq/e@iNCuXO/ZguLFR4d9jzYLqIy2ZbQ5REAptnrDUh19NFuwtELR25efdCbDkE3uhpo/4U0n4UDvSNhlH6qBmqTrN55mhFX9YxaFA5xW6GVZ/7gJl0GsBAV9yS3uXXlEPMaHt00m47h7UpJOS@SlBdEE3ZLykR8odbV16@SSwiqXYYGTMEwihcXbLPJ9eDcIR5@N73BZ8z9UIG6raAVeya1QPJeoHRSvcs@HptDaXq/F/GOBnUFdkBiSpRkIy02VKU5@qlmJ23XlE28Y8J3Kbfk@@uJmdRYS1FFCePq2on51nPUmaDSqnYNGjsLLa2uMSrTFlzfZi7G2Fto@thaZT91Y5FSFiWi8tCojngSuRk/fcST3uSvPIwweugLzri1CgqEobPiXHVSzjF@sCn4EAaDlr0nSppMy@9j@42XPr0u86LZOtRu/5r@MApGtAJoFsLbAsNoOH/pXXQb272Ofx72Qp/WafAzfysSD48jfkSHnQ96NxHHNpKolVam1ih5Fv8y4oYN7/G55IblmisaBn3HNlMYDkbVC3ETwTvnMAJM4tcyf/fHfaTFZZ6sJYUy6funbI9Xcjdmln1cmlZYTvQBQAu4zTELCrlDOuSLSdbl042JDGfzMlg4nqmc8t0ZFnspjJ8TifgYJoWxQWbCLMFuBFZmMzE@ad16LfZBOICjpWAnQByeyOHPno8Y4iRFfoSlQFmVnhWtonKKcgs/hHgYzSb36tN/MvaEwJ9Av/R4GrdMYwQWcW3jbSmS9Yr2Mkq4sHlgyDKaJTFJsfA87FrXDznKxe041HTyaBY12PKHlCLtZm@CKzEiHVr4IASf0yCR0xi5mFSW1bLLfjugglSHTnE2wwZ32c/y4MchruycQTBta8iOhfQsUjWJSgilPGZea6MsPpXvHjGrq/fttTECVqaZnFnRwp2s0Vz4Bkoo8yuOtXoDEsbZMeppU4/laNjrL9@TejNlx1TPbNNo3XTdOw2BhdkqNFk@ajFpKyM8jjYy4/iMMU2aYmxpRjyE5Ss/x2w@TsTbSgPjrdIY3UGHWTRL7KbiSSXu75aMfUyK17DoNRNNPKQYdzgp3Yi/nzSo4Y3ZEkTDlOVVgyVGAyKjMZJHC9QYmWIq3Z9CzH0a9zF6tIhyqLdFtLP7ZyZRx43kjMtTk5Rycgl6wnE7Lm2SXOq3YXwBN3Gi4cZCKlY4b70RH@WVcmdwMowEAQitOMgl@1Cyg5t01hgfcXSAttOAtVAJkoieNm0Lh9jpf0ww9sqvN3e0xUNjlCudbgik2xgSrSo41zxI5r45vZ40bhnKBCloiE8hRdyiCdl0cf9W/dm2UD6CIKU5WVv6Fj00xlUrhA39sZMat9CBk6p0ydSISg@EBosGGgu0SjnvBLJchfYXDoTjYd2ghxEtIOSzg58VXQLuvNeLMbVR5LY1QhZXk1tGm6tym1IkYSh5B/n1UBRVlxeuBCAQjKl8pUQQ4NaUscehALvesTkvhajuIypYKWFY0kf2iprYeU5JB1F1hidrVo7itBzPbRi5qUBIsZieJ0GEdJbpWRIoNNFNxcXK8XR6e5IcpBAb3heKU1foXknTMO45ISCHwS66iUQ5KSmvqDmYE5@suanEmL859XnRSi2OpxJ9YgxPcqXx1GfFVGqq2tXVdNFUSaKHa9eaSiRSuDbCsVT4c//x1RTb5XlsE2otMlJahrbPRphyWmXSui3/a6Re8KVso2MYePbNcLP8akiIlZRT9vkO2NUyHxnAd/ufbq2xTDWY6FgB7JfOXHZxZEHIGmsWUz2ahZWu8bQXOygwa9peW70/2t1NuX09GxlDo8tgsFYsFsHEZ7bze2Nbja2ksFdI5y60rzqdQv/mL4P3ZwWW/UHAIQHKZgUdUJfQoIjyvcG5RIYADpQVuXP6IivW@lftth2CASeU6DzqNsmpvSEonoDC2Ojl/RFvADFIPcH@ggaifb@oePTd@KJoaijmGIpKwyT4OmtOz4g8@NCGfXZ8UsXAIJiNNRPNW25l8wtmEEQ24c5i98Xul8Q8Ofs66HR6nvqA6MjwFLDwbbzA7q5doChZcMLIt3uvIvZH66ngOuxY94qRxeZ1gDMTk4kzYfzCwzf@QXBeu@072ZOfszStUJNX0MwV@Kf2VPY862pn8fcAK3xIaN8r96Xfd5pMp/HMNNXrEZw8EUaPS97UtU8qi8t7Yppmd@cGUaejm2dnDdR0l3UB48ueu5dbMiN7TNzsp9tSGzQsCgyNE3yu3K8Erpr988Ti9bDdvp9U5DAA0rHfJRElEsqfE4h8BsAjUA8/oie8aP@Uo2G9O@ZQRBQcBOuYlDso0ECBTOZhs/LbjVOtVtVSf2VFVatb9JDLqepWVe3gw9aW2qH3Lbz/UFldW9sQmbvjfqGPW@bjN7VFMHiHc6V5MdihV0qr4N4YrLXRxUuFypK3sdSovNjciAon1S1c66enf/@v//3f/9v/KFT1y//Cyxa/nPwcZ8rn84Wl5pelH75t4P1k53R56exkqX@6fL4BLvs7ew3v1Yc5PzEfzQ/OMosyC1hf2Y7UrLPZ@4wuqkwsv0t/8JmkS1ktNqPCov4aSeQolrGLzcD6HuAe5Rkt4U3QgfGlPCGxSEBH2I6n3mkGMMCj@YYoSbjADlTKy9mK2biHO5g4Q3yqsqg98bDOeh3gTkviSQF3cWnGyoXdKOhiB/yadV5pXibj0284bGj@Lfz8Njrf6t2qR58c9aioHnnqUTbLP6X15/TVXSqEuJ0r2Wg5kM16lJIcLcDMUEUhK3q8fuBYO2PkzmSWOGQPIBk3FZxZbsF58eqPL8tIwLXoPLOAWJ9Ktkj4kAlFFr8sdb9Rt3yhHN@yqas2rCg09CqGK7NOVOL@hQrkR2IIkNR8KQQp96hKnPTxjWQ8FcwX3dcZjibEgEHWg1e7PO7xgeaipa62eU6tpRDmiM3n5Svmxg25DM1oI0XqTxDgAxVZThb5JuHy4nJGrLytVnIz5Ra23T7NfGLrMAqGxjZdCv1NWUwg1tw24Za6@l6LNuSW4xWVDePjFauq7Ljtt8pYRS6vOsOwr68rcO0YUF/i2r7JSEKPMiCBIz77y5MjjDcKjKeosW6RYFkj1eqh6TISuvpqOnWwm5eTI4sIhZ8dGttfx8a2W@BbIoYdhAcYqdiUr@2HnUh7XRkwsc/9wRmiA/ptDqg2lHMz3s9DzNYxjHvtGOk8Q2aT82Q8U1MW@wP//NL31OJe72jgj@o0bZHmM2zmXWohXDABCQw@XfW05hmEpUW6S5gicVPYcgjBCzojHR5N@jYb3zlBl5qhoN2uYBCk2IkpGXxN9dUYHROu/o5OsFGeEN7xaaQWsSx5YWmkIWXtazM8zCaGTsbUYI@deOBkM4JqPDINL@hCV5hoL/nglyR5Bz4CdN1ZfQtQX0VYf476MTudB10/NTn1Oxlz0b@woWRexHjmUJRijZTRUJ6Wkoh3wIr0yJ/TXiBkbjLujDILjrPwKdLh3BbteYSdfMe2@AVfhXEAOg5gxjdD1HE3FGE5NkMlMTDyqs6W/wSh3fHPCb/RjT8CK35adH58UHBPfv7UPX3kfOp@/fS7y5hokWxm2Zxa1IfZRmLpsUIzY8FLvRqrtMi4GvzUTWf41FVyh8UiASFScE5@Lpx@LRBCnxZd91Hh06IQJNVlwKQwv74CwBcm0FxMY1FYzCy4j1zT@c6PJVfR3Mq/6EP54MovYWEWlbxNT@ucQZtA8T3d367kyklUeLZafLJaekIrofPgNjcIrjDf5qKrs@CWVIkIy1maej79nuKGFCG@3Ub@Bn28pXZKWBO5exLpS0pahOphzvVkYraiMnnhCcpPVGZ3qbji4sZ5fBw@YsHvKWI5k5d9QYnpoMV9DubPqHeJevwIcm38dohwJKwMxEaEt1BzgGyCr8ziUNcMl2W@55RX2/DdykCoewuL1mzR7XVzWllz88sbUKJxa6bzrPisOD5GJ4ZoaoQuaWVq@YEqbf749N/@5/5vi8PFzdXChwH9Dhd/W1x/tiiP9EBvj83b9eLm4gtkW/@2OCrQGpgen/7b/6bym38hOEgZvaA/m2sG1vpocTNX4SJfFzfX6aG0ukr1/p9//Vdqw5Ks2BCLdanhKUZsw1Bk2@8y71K6qqOVsixdTsQKX8wCDLEwpLU5vcAw6nb1WZG36Ra1VcV1oD1fGXsUPcWzYdaQTYVkJ8PYU5BmJAUqqCAnII0JRVtZthvGbAPMm6CpfnmYX49oBfCLNueIq4xNNx5GMBlakmURdaAjNdJ6Xh42iz9mY/OOctbYlGwYFRJLOy1rnz3eIHZ41wuGYTNtJWGG62XTvwnO8uDDfNC6ojVVN@r0fh0UroklL0urzwptbO4X2I670GdIuf4o/zspgjoYEC0M2ejUUwPqgd4lXHh5HC2IFPrd@EzKxJMkLbsfNGUPKx2TmLLIHT9PjofRnHyiSjv8lxR4RM7UgSCtWGmfulRy/6CssitxRsnHa14X2Lxj41jtAiMn1rB9lk35DLcBu4OmPfnq4JwvIXEpeF2XLHm/1Wr4Os3JLGRNqDQvs3ARdPqVbFvcu8N3Kk5MNP1FzZwJJRdiByGXY0EHWJfB0KcleiXLX7AeT2qAmxR91hq7ikvI2tZ59aq@VeGoK3OqvpGqb6hHoSUk9cQ8Y3ljU3Y2kS0VbFUOggaO1KZWTLVFJmjzIM8/wCCSbqm3cS1BN4dvQBLVkuZoqzK72zxeCxOP3ARyZ0@2FiVydWYxufzomRxygxq6E@rNS2UkIOAFtwwLZXo/lBsQFRNmNOxmxJ/fWLLx76HBcBv24UrUdlsnzkdlWupeI/ZNOOS7lIpIoP3K2jbYGZk9YtCxi604BG0WGy9ZFyzVLvNiizOa7ihzGGjjEiqblX2qk6aKw8u2dfRaCRRBH7LF0urjJ2vrT589R5SzBd3a6WBQKI9VQP/CJxisUTu0yMb3SiW7nJVPCEE9WSWgTwOLAziYdd24rnH7fOM@qJSKGlgxy7BuOIyGFNfblQwygTgI8pgRaI3iDLKO82P5BA07/dRyv9I/4m/jH5AZzrij9YX0Vj@8SzxTZS7F4UCFBTM7xXEew4OKq1PsvEGvfQBvEwFsXYXtqaI38AAxvBj0rs4vbO7Ia9dWRzRgiODslxorqFfBMHEwZmEFXVRvONSt2xcVA@9ksgUwysWUAJ1PgNMw034rfW1pitGxTJMQPGvixiqOEC3TUZudmTu7PVXb2xlHbNEOQ8dw87ZlKyl37MkMDmQQq9dq7hFRV3u74KukWiZ5Ka/KLOCKyFfi6/A@7ko3EYjaooqR1aw3DJ15ZCkxLyauTZOi1I/AawrMUvFuUpp7raYVIIgRhHo3KRZiXnyeY5MswcnuZIxT8HK2bNmIvg2jiB3M6cqyrrYo5UwcVWAhMwMg9m2KWWlIsYwe5ccaB16W3kYwR7kVja0BbYYcr1SDqTk5zARb3UbiABtRxw0t0P763randmr0Z/fDjgdFeav6E9odh3iejW9J41sqq/qu6QLbWyzb3MJm6jdcUSJmKWqHsQmCEL5tiYoYJF4DavVdTXsZ1CepsX2acAXY1ddKuNkd1YMEjl54D2RBL95jVxx8XYe/lWXzalLSxC5V9LCQLa75A9uiyUJSawxJSHkPEKvjIGJHLQm3LyQMLxborHn7eu1iGLu@O52nUywrCypS23cLRPY0z86kzDy2WNVssVpGP87jC@bbubxxFrR7@i5azBx38MaDP8YbufszR@7/C@ao/XO447HmjsdlyB7hjthtON/o5DDsvSkcczbiObjRCs9D7A@1rVc0ouhZAFjgAUPcIaXEUhFtmyFOlDM9YWV8PoKR0OoaLgb8ocY/0Y1/UobM5ced4P/Vxuf@wY1f041fK2OumdLzWrWz3K3/Y1qcqIRO@sPU7oW6K9ncP9rSdd3S9TJm0ynd/J/e0tx/UEuf6pY@LcNjghw4iPv6@dwsmkj1cLteT8wt8hnttMtBHPvpXOli7dWqZGnx0O5cRRcVaOvqD@P/TOP/DNKInxCGDmcRsW1ovJaX5alclhfNknc5FC5ZSUukvcYzutVePWEl6xE9QYmQ5o2tgV6okELuSWJy2pRP9MdE@saTz31xFtmug2Xi4NxaQMuKsOQmQ1w0Xx0kc3U9nld22Aey2j46eLPyX4QMl/5nfQuNkEfX3gSdjplJ7CXYUex1SjfGag5gH@o1R4pVNDkZ2aG@7R2zy8JsqcaOLcbmxemLBDlqw/kfraUuoW9YUbmxZUS0yevyZlUF01yzvJAv1HbJNL3JusV/iEufay59XlYHemEwi1S@3vDTvJis01bX1ubNAVIqjx8MwKJH@eeMqv8L)

At least gcc 13 is needed. Compile with `-std=c2x`.

C23 shares code with tcc because both of them don't support trigraphs. They are separated with `*u""`, where `#define u "e"` (tcc doesn't support `u` prefix for strings).

Answer (score 4):

## 404. HTML+CSS ([QEmacs](https://bellard.org/qemacs/)), 17048 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{ #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; x=echo 403;$x||echo 350;exit#;a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295# [']; print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68')));[exit];'"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';#wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;



















































































































































































#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#8""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 ?\在ｕ2\0C05+---<?ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._#:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({27acf46b-af0d-4edf-8b25-70b17fb8660c}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0kiwRAAHyzyOrq6urbfdUvdVffey2SzQZJkEQXCLABsors6uqQNLtay/bMejSyQ5Y9vrJmPCuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzkJgGAVWdVXtje8iyoC@Tx58mTmyXMyEwddwx/99KcJvNgT114MbXfKpqY/ZX3POjE9md1esFuG5Rc0XRAw1b43nI1NZ@pXhQRTGbMNZzgzhiYbWPbU9LLMN03WNW33FOI1xnZnzsw3@w3w6Yw55im77/SsPkBgU/fYdKw3pgdxecbumPbb8dsp67njseH0fTbxLGdKsQXGnhjgGcx6x8zo@lPP6E0t14GoImPPHdsYd/sGo@QTz@SZSgxA9Y4pz2pMmbGHruebUILbM33fxcAKBBqe5T7Yf/TRhfRqjn1kAFIT25xfKF5V2aeW6fUv5tDYJ0d3714M1dlXJNdhdy@jpObZ/mzq3p9ehF9g@0PTMZgmV2TtYmQRiDk17XKunLsYVYL2NKdWb6UciLhredC6RtCKrGc40FrYljvMHE@mCybx9jdsO2pbnxk@m/kzw6Z0zmzcNb0woT81vKnlDNmpNR2x6cjyo3yU2p8YPVPqm7Y1tqZmn9kWZHIHARQA7fTZsbk4dT1o8gCm69gLyGj2rIGFWUI8ACBeqenI5HDGxgIa2ZlC52AG8wEN2wyhpYUEpL9jdmdD5s6mk9mUAW59yze6NgDtLljfHBgze5plXYgDIlP46ch0gs4M4GQAceRyrF7NCDVz2eeNfp/loB8DHscms4BqhFaV6TqEM9cDqkGqEKMAGPVrXkdzDm0GTTRwq6yQy0H8YRSC2Bq27wbIrKKGkQ6MVWozhPvEc4eeMQZq9E2i6Sf3nzC/53rggx@m5ePpKjA9Y8p2d1ny8NGdJGtEzSJ7XSFqojo7gyZIhJHsxLBn0EPiLeFC@3hRbgGbLLmVrLIkkEXLsXye5WHYlplWACKpuQo4YPxrugq/ItPKLK/CCCowXSsls1jWwDOGlm1ySEOEVMLOD0k0uOfyTFfLPOXQtQc8WY8KLDG9zIolViqwEtwrrKJBiQg@z9RKAX5F@AG0CqCjwk8H5HIaB7bs/9Bfsc8dsIExtuxFUAIV0WMFlZUAKuCtAnStDFDgqev40@FHqK1ecdjTEVB9ZJwAeMm2jpErmRFjwqZU4KHs7CjEGZH18uL9ERYPJATiFcqsBMUXgRp5QAEorJWh@EKOV8QfmbYdZBv5mI2wLeXgB5iXgBZlaIUc0DOHBC3BD/zA9zRgcBpwMw0YlAZMRdPArWMRkK4IcUVo0mKeFzMy/GMoiJej9akBgLMDGBUpjsxMRSIBBGgxBqSG5s5Dh9CxQxR0BvgDLqUiA35WVlk5z8olBvSs5Bi0jwp4YW9RgY@qgI@KwKAPqNAJVMBJBWqrAFTVC0yIEVvVMR7y6pAXSKPmIU8e3NBwahF/kA96hwpFqlCmplWWnRFw0wpQ34JOvVQrQuuWIA7opgGuGnQpDbDVyhCPectAwzJ2Yui6nBAG0gFaBbs99EUgRgHwIbiQFtxaSef0M@zJyOgi1@Y5uwPMWsThUEQyQtYcVg@eeaQmoJIDMDgSAH0NeoBOowae@ah4WwUgTQRv9i1i1LYFPEyNKFTKUod8ZUymS7KpRcJospiOojCNh7nAQC1ggubQ6C2iSBiB2ShyGVrUMVQjnrsElMtjqA8c1p359hJI5MhrVJR5YtnLsDKF9U2jP7D80bslrnkqpGsaU8c6XpZSKGRjRDViEUWMWAkq6fG0U0uCaWs4QteyLloJ00zcqIFWUFZVQq9rDmbO0JQq5Rh@FDOdeVOYYJZlVniwZw2HMDcv4ahZqiZNmMvgAmFo6/pUiAKRulimZ8E0fpP1RiBYRJEVDr9SWcLQNYSxMLo4u0sgjcFsUMH5a2DNWfdmj2aPJYI60ak3siZh4urGxLHGpULm5WKsbxDl3pRzEXvGqy2/ci0nlWTJtHAuwJzDJcz4jA0T26c4W@H8i10X5leXpIcl@0w54QyZBqKtTvYw@9rARqFRegbOxDgvmTSvhnCsqcygEBAHTfcExVeaHFeK8WkC7XoorYK00zc9j2FaEHH9LE21/qzrm69nKE8t8RrA3G3CFD8wLDtCgOYRY0qCADyTPpS3WEV74LljmmzGOJXarjvZILbAxH2KgO65p@YS9eW8bkwmNkhPEG5y4Q2QOTVI7iYhPV4qRwgyYT5ocABIRYHUYXlmj2gfVB1y6yCfrKJYZVrjpo5QbsfEKh0GC4gcPuZxZrZdBXnH7DG9ofTNEwVDuOi1KnIhDqEwBiJVAKJrgMyMmBMWEaSbmkxi3lHYsr47Xq0an1/vR1UfWSgg2afGAlpvAFOrOTfGINkzFJ9h5LIx9BjegtgSoLtgte6zvuskpxGUUw@EWah0VBMSmJEmU2tsghbkQhZs8TwhjbM7YdZdQFcmauVlUns4JhcIJQsXCcUD8rEAPlhA7OvPekg1LNtyqAeBqOSjrO8Bq@RhwtRjrZYBPw/kukmg6cnowITPELWYouDz0R5I4D2CiLKq6figXvgys1APg54/dAfQ2U4tqDswLMi6hN0jIiAJoqC53JMFIjl2oPGxzSzWm0wYhMOkBN3zbq4Moqj7ymJvINIegSrRm3negs0n0BLWGFJNe@5gAL33jTkZAQg27rPeogfDExoZe4/Qd4nB9Car1Vz6tk1I46BycvDk59nQBLKD4DpALRW7/LICkwlVgUhhOFyodQygFFahN1kQWYTEMsfAdWUM77umT53F9Y6joY@F@eaQhgaMs8GSGY1RSIde6pBy0QfOEwwvhI8FCmsrg0UFveAj04Gh04NeCYMemg/bdJ8NQNmOibCobxi9njmZBv3EJXZmOTG5//FdlPspVAqAyf5I2L7Fdi/0Gkga9ZyYLIt6EKI@CdQRA3ltoNFLJHhEqifnLPbiUvGQ4uRC6eJLTLOCwUtxAw4TGhKoBBGTmE2RlSB3tHoj5IVT5DYkb8No82aXqw9h8eK9MZMGUdmIjQpsR5CVKAjx2AxDgp99GZA8sRFWYyUAk64EXAPa8MdrILsRknY/HiorhgxM8TqgY9dx10AFYkZwMclqDLUFdcZnyDUMO@qMNFz8lTZChr1cZMKJDObQycT1YGRwprOgFQVqsljvChTxVDRXpGV2e3VqhSkjiRP@FGdByDCxDegLOMRwpIJmZQCnACbGFWXgeS4vMYYwjXqCFeB3SqyfdyaYSx3HROXM8BYcCFQPpmcoaMEszwM2eIKTBJ@DwslEpn4Kc4LR7yNnRXLQuL9YuIw9@mDWteYXtfEeBsqvfOHE8NgAFXEPhA4YRKnkwE@maxROOWNRouJOpgpl5XcRElIiGZo8NQDdHiaJu8Boni2cXkpcGWJilomz6aAspsGBGbmMxj4GVeEidqg@YKcZH8O4Jl@NDWH6liS4SxhGmGCEImOE4YGcAYMQtMxKpd812FvgHh6T5gdcFQlVElXOR2WZTj8qKyAE4hKvr8yL8L0eOaTYrIY1wORUc5okVgj4gZSgjCIEKEowt2IASXs8juQaHjhzaD2OpbgokmZnkfALE0CKkLFA@LB61rQTiCs3b4aCy1a9Dp0NpClgm/10XKMNFy5l4NSQWCZpJChEnrrPpjg2UmmoLyY@59iA2AQ9td5gZ9ORByOO/OcCJAKyCg725JCwQTs/so5n/YsN7WAgJhJx1IHQZPWmYk2AyZ@PhvpVVE2uUBW03iRSFTsv5ifQlzovhWKDikEyz/RR/K0HqMRaOIUYBH11LYl41iBs2aEPFj07EAm4CwY750ZdQP84WNCKGFE2kAnCQXtppHIgOBw4HPZk/@hePRiLPFLpWk51JcB2e4ZNwduYXAzzPrh/@@n@05/vrIFhW93qxQDFypeLONXO5tLQmSl5Watux2EsAd/pXA0bM66mEYUgmknuPCYqLXowucxDcj5@@pWLJAFJCMlBJYAbfxdEGp4GhC6ha/ijC5MwG2YyUGSUJUzLpPsshBk5EHWMN0J8nszevMHGu4jUJAhHzOyZwQGEgcp9J8wnY@QFASyM6g74jEh5QQq1HNxwWLriKUN8PkKp@SIyJErHusxHj@8ePq0T2GBdTaIkij8FWcrw@jL0eXsGKvi6NMD@wNVjGXmJOMrThOtaAvd6KwReti3bAB8AoK4ju0yyx2HV/BHgfnCxbhQq9aIeQH6CcFGujMtDvS@KaAwPnOJ6qPKum0UpYjlZRUFrZ6wodnXa6hUKZilfiU9bvWWZ/ThQ2hyAeSCUGz2IOvYlDJGXUmQgVgfoP3twCXGfhEhQBaQQM99mMpXl2wJqL5LFkr5yABqaa5vyp8TxRCamFSUZ7g/IPZ@Uz1j6w7k1TeXS/KmmIS2Uvr9/X7sTJg6WrGklg5QG1MVxZvIGuM/X86GPOK7tDl22A3m4dBgWCGLTxmruD13nUgsZGIhVTeBWIfBfXLgxJjDXWG9IcaRccXWVbzoajn8KXFot6kgkohCBUii9/Mo4MYBcy3o/u/@1Q5hE1EIuF7lzdAEJYnmIXOjqxUIpgElQkBzgs7aC0bbhpdEeRkixfTusdMDoooz7y@i1gcQxZWVt@rUofexeovgrd3Gha0EI71rgiJHs/qMnD@4/Ony4/1lrqhUKK/58rlIEwkF5XZCF5BGnG47WHT40sVoILgFjw8PhBVxgBgpKuGs08z1g3DImkTkCG3oN33BNfeyOnKSfvliZU4yVXjk93oUe4uDjSYOMoGj3bVRGPL5rjfM59p/RdDrxq4oCo3w068qgtCqveq5tDBXKBxODbSsqqi73H@O6hr8uByDjL0yegy9ugeiwoBVEwx67oLzQ3jeyBpbi4GnVyraGI9CFcYPc9NJy1IOpNkofNATQlZWobsSAyQe0DZ5hO4m8a39Z1cq8X6s5La@IYbKV4Q9ptwYmqE4pmK2AFOkLXta62brJFsClEdJFIAkm79Aih89wLrAZCJK0aop6fkgc4ha4Xoq8gmj0eoarucCllEIuX1KLBQXUMlDTQGaVcM1NGhvT3kiauhLAk9wBrRvEeuHA7xnOQN4JHCGyIPfdgKrqzRetltMGAb11k3DD/efmot1U2@kau5xlJ0ifrkHvXake9t0wAPouOaFr0pNt4Gd94zI76xs0uvpMmY4nwZwjTdjDfRCk3rjAr/tmfOxhBiUeqeyspFUw8TtlzYKQjVkFvCGlFBhQMNNC11MQLwmEXhQPoecA34plYMvVjEhgWkxHwD90ljogV/qyhIvBesA1VlHBRWF5sgCWR4mQaUs6IhRGUIETDgFRSYIKhBIPxic5CvyoSYyVod6PQ89ykz5t06BohQu2/gTakda7ezhR@LhEOYUJOhp8OFFA/8J5gp2aSVzKN3y@YAqZguMGYX5QFyMItDEQLYo70QEL6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV29FyoRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBDj0AbGECoJmXlF9nlFeEkUslqlY8c9dRBa12RlqWtN@X6DO/Nw293qx@sGyXWNpwFoVLnY1EL7812zxxd6eWaqBeihBhubYxdXM0DAI25kUhUMvreP6qiPi@YwsnMSbloCfIndOgBG2jP5kpU0Rj0OevUhS049ZV/6mmJIb2BAXSHeYeVjTRw0@lFIgNWTFrRQEyzCkoDkjinRp7Tkg5G3Q4k76FrYs0Sj7k5M56LayZXSVLpGJyKSSb4PdZbc2tpKVpONZBZce@DaRdceujLg2iOXRC5MJ6OLcmTJhbFNyoFh7eR5M4Q8T7exD8xReHljTVJGs1rV21mjqQZPDZ9paAqgPKSW8AFwkul6HZ3ptNg4xW0jUCFidT/AvvOs51mTgAQfg0zC/fHhJQbDyzNrqB5fTZFx3QO91UQpN@UlW81cq906a/UzrfNkFnOna0YdVFTgn9PUWB567mwCsmMzX5WAvaaberVd69aTueROKlWWbCjISKdvlNMZg9M6lTShT6VarSSQNKBOszfyCN48q6XTEaEAj4EFio5tp5LyWRnK76bb6UwS8qaTWZgZ6skk0IX2PH2qNC5K8E5015oDKWFgwiwb39YgHk37Yzhcv2ZORgsvniBa@ANBHxfxl8dm8HQRTiRxRv2G54/LlCuLDaHozdOBfI3rhyiyTRZ8ghE4pi1l5ZBWOPWfSIOxOzWUT2TQ2@TYjJ3cSiqSBJMxxXBIVO2Hlo9D2HBMd@bHFzvXrsFi6RB6NJoBswxPymWhV1kTweyNXJbcvgXQWbTlhIwfd88kvgcXAuj3ZPghE0XBCPdrQMChs00W8EU6FUYLQyohwVlPuD1QKE5ey1FpNcrDcliQNXRcz5SAJJBDoINcdDxQaIRb4/dp8e3S9BPE0qyKU5llAke8a7sG0Zaz69iW1GQcy@8MMctTsy/YwD8GwB5l3hae2Vd2BNoodr0RzBBQG@TEWtRa4yBCcf1JX57OIauQwjk/HskVTJB7T1lf07RirzCohnHYK4DYI2gkVIwd0LLDKEmFyHTQyId8ZSpcJnj0@M4hX76h@R5neFzK64zd/gxE20B1e2o6wyw7hP5kOe7YAjKE@d8c209dd8oXGsCzaXGI6@3WeGYbtOx0cWXoynw9t@vatBp1VdZl@pnnG7bB18HC2P1PHoK68fzoWV2uxhIpxsn4yrJxKXR9sZye9@PbnrTlG@5Q@bxjitsFEeet8AAqspkgoogRs@D4KbRRGF7C8HBI4TZOEF7G8DEePQVxPVjIIG8UGCSsUEI8jopn74LAMzV3juEb1cAonUrpuOy6xPZM1Sj8ZDoYrATrFHwsIWuyl8F5CubHUlfU1DhKBZ4Iz6iupIkDKlKa6KjqxnQlSscP2MjR5ubD6BzEyLTD3c2nILHgDh5M@jbKVaA3oZbAj5OaIORPcKOGWDdu/7EeyMH@JSkWBttE4qmFxBYNIJjcFBRphG2FBcvvNRpCjhtsm/qcrbpelq/s7Db4RjuqdR7XKBW@MbDdARC7jVp45m9TMiwpmYySEVTCDXJQNelswaWqRidFfFrvFyhLTfAV0GjmWk5qzUuH7bdJxScyDJjYas1v5LTPQDXCg5vbN5WhWaNjVhvoVQtjkoEM210wCSQ@TMXXznsj4DMsM18lJbTPzBm4dl/iG3XQYRhX8bCBgnMS0YHS4NywaXnhWVI6zMuzIn@NHUO9BPdCkzYuJ4gdXI0AwfA5Y2@PsydvWROmvBPZn9jWtM3O5anbGQWHtZyLR1y5DOp5xsIXgmM2dbb/9KNPmrk2hyCMDdx8K/NWnIcnpUFwBkEJj7SDCw8LTa0pSQJ0GMLC@qoyIDWnfRpAH2DwAmosKiioEaL@1ny7rMvABGU5ZSLm/mKcZWb6XB7YxnRqOrzP8R3QzeTmW1VBMXUqfi/Y96iyHG0OgWRqYRygWGPPju4cPn0qQ8/1U8lD3ESqwnA0eiMQUDZVOqRkvPJVdqOfZDcwTxpXDgQYaqB9dIL80Klr0OlB/4DSkXcMTS8FgWnc/@lBMG25UUYuoQUEwiNfvSnRKAKWMtNQJwJWXYv/c4erWgGeVejxGaIkkDt1swq0tdLyzLFeyz5MNCS3QpJAWYX5or6dIi62raaDM31j3L0GDYuERqhBs8mkN8DlILHI2u0aP4YAaVEB84ZIXVGkpqAD9XU1bPo6BINIQxCC7PV37EUzJ1Xame11oOh8W3AWntc/BhchrIL2zbXFbqdovF8ayBwHvh3JOfdzUqcvvAhSZdvcIfJlb0oentkipkNHvFaPaq0eBINBhqyEVoOwIiFLSARvKgR9luKJ84POg9koIJVmZxHRNSQ5e/uWaMi2NUY0BJfKeGOch9onMKYHLtTmQfCWQlw6oNEanGXBMdsSxFDNWt0sxhguwisnF6RT6USM5@PSoeUcu7TlFLk6OVktoEQY5R4f25dz4jlYuq0kjXDgabVN2Pnj7oBuaxLQzkuwp08BtKYfyMIgRBrKU3rQ8v6aklfPsawUG5yQpZkW3Ex6fU1KqVKmxINu19qUFIiAR9PC55pkwKSwP2tyXlbD1x5wKQbmI2BcXHtZVv3iESi2QvfgKG/w/K9f7wP9L7fOCCYKXPyMHB2YurGlpMHGxgqyoodu6xuWr9HPbMsgwpDrOpA9w4MqGXbkWA@azgFIEkz/Y9zVCFoc@ibeQGq8optxzPmmZPhcX8i6fT0HWGZvU9oLR8J4UbQDBYpdn4jAhSDLpEzEungjmHO@CxRTsZGNXY9UeG6LUWfm7T6aTWf8DoLrtY1oTfB31dgMUuYKRlc1FX54/oom94zjWd@VJsfDSE4trkm7rD1tQ0sgDgQ70h10rq8@ryA/jB4@NyVbTm3KKT2u6xW@M/MnUpe08D730UAYX1GCZ/P7piRW8B5h5NhMNcum2wf2xAA6dJTgQIaCx12lGNGsC2S2je4CZZDRF@9l0eEG4Dj1XiaT0zfsbk8mm/OjJkn5K5X1uedyj9Nj3RqBwo/USnwVjSocHLK9plVhurLGhi1p/ZhzIzNfdzbiUtJoW5Xy4Psf9BLIlZ0cJ6TezDa8peuKLr7EI9xG2LQiHUwbT6yeC@LAhKklWdXCqSM2YRDLDE/nLQvCE810i53AsNaRMXyjRYpc61mA25viqdUNfeoDGBo/LYpncmOdRHY3UarnnuJvo/gwAtWU39fPaG/WYvUBzEmye7YB8/jG6WBlcRAXH6/pqKeWb9JtPWGP1yI67dlrw1eHQLjsF1/Gu65b@5bt@uwZ3a8i0NADKvD7@g4dp6VlOBIthsfdV/Cg8JjFskENe@jaxfJQMeC2sdVn3gD5fvD8UA4XcShVvYZDheKP66jBcyNfP1a84@saiN6Z9PCIbcx5xRS7jk0Fey@baweKAW7cra/Z3VyZcsoKX@rbUDBuuZwai/D5M0wdm0gbTh2TBYnTIN1hhkoZHFOPi9g/S2n5q0vrfxhTugS2dF0lYo17bJswWdH9UpMyLad@wRxqLvfhLGpgz8yZuVbReNx9ZeIb/lcoGR@OVC6oxnawUo@bA/h2TJTqTaAZfhDWOE@j70pmYthWz7xelFllahOQvieoOj8BxxN0XM4xdGaTlVZd0c6cp1eTbDQJh7TbX8EOY74oHypfIymtyOe@Sb8rNSau4eEZtXohl8sFAkxsx2XFc5UmpUd5X1n8vlIwhSxLXqbFXTYv5lxfBpElfgpyIwvSNin2lLhSURzLMacLvH8gN@26rv1FWgqYKr6z7IK2KtFp36ta7JK4E7zHwpZLFz4ueHQHmxYt@GwT6JZAH1Sar2r0@JbQB7WmhJueY9yQWvVevXwT22C6rhR8vxbXhPj5X3uzLBmshqhyWS5dOeq4hOp2Tdvgj3kxfxW8iqxfCW@VaQSbtbi5y7d0l1vxiQtMabIAYll90FJG5tgk7xVSvtFHax3BY2OiuYu/TdFz0@wp80OztynBxAK@4OB9ZQ85JixNXQf0qykeNUQ9xcbDrEHoJg4c7vqtJfL9sTE0ufmYqzjlcsECT9NwtW7pXL90UeUnaHqQbWkXZHOXgEF1bC788LkW4MNFD9p1Nr5@ue3C4O/hGugHjPZNp2gvT7HOyB05I3PEj65Hvk2DA/rjlJv7uQp1wHo4wtN0k8nKKfs4PW3Xtj@EnsgaOaN03cFanA7x/Vt8eewLweUv@wePaxfvjCnnHejYOGpG5gzmJd@duhNTIt@mpDYu9PD7Jh4ablL/rCtIV@r5QJHw@bPCv1a3HBrudDKhR2diz3y6UVaJXpu@Tm4a8KMpdC7T9YbyG3fclYNAOTi3Qlvg61lM15r2RvjeOu/Z5tDt9kbWdUgHtjKUcMmHez9Id0XKWEy6g8GybQF5vYWM/aUej3@Gj/ubGj1YPeLTWuS4Ql5Zt0JHb4ZLE@O45/PVUHSxKi4Ix0Yjf3@8Sm/gV1/PrOkSaOwsU7S8y7cl0LEJ9@D0xEbJil7TWLLh4FTFxl5KQjoK5JKZA4FH3VTs6jm32BDTdX7bhFC8loRR7FzKFyF3cPaHVget2LothK/0r5VDS2snOWc0G/qXGSZfru@DiIa3zcsWdJw6tmQNc5bhBI9NZNZsBd@zhGcHZK6ZeeWeSuHKTRVKp9qS4Vrw6MADmm62cQ3NtiY@vzNpsHErLjjLBLr4xf1CTpvFemU6aJi@OeBbIOi6TkQcux6eRAYZROrhTjquoCMz54IXZ1yOOwSmLtlsmThMu0lsWXtMaH3zR3Om9Nkjc2jgWesH1hQPa67pFdRl1x0vuhb2V2eGb311BjXb1NnQaATfhvTi1gXQtwbeQ2No9e6tNESEZEDg4KQnf6x0fwy63BanI8vHE02R44qFKexyvBNjr@uA3rAm5cV1@8hexnIA8Tcx16Zet7buThb4wtqCXFctq1tTWmUNnptUx02HwK5E4nQ2nsz84LEeBzozFV@FHh9TuH9qAXDpNbBWNjLs6fqV6tiSK0hhwaS4dG6Sxr9m2e6Qfa2cYyC0gRCGwvmajnMbpucneCDHc9b0RCr7A7c9caFD8njFXkPbmvhehWNNr17NmU7xcE74xMrwmQPfUFAe4F2@9UUhSEfrKfLgell/@Xb0NfM79Lxn7szrmeiMTJ7E1YKgVPMgPH2Mb3S4aLLlNK6l9Vwbhhc47LVDpuc6s6nkzZwrZ4XilbNCFQ1exboBS3318OHzdLw30Gnt66TQ0CTa0rXxwMCFTmY5IIht5qOrqUNd4g431fSUjgpfk2cf7Un1iF3fcdfpO08WMIF8sMIEzH82vmP2cNvw2rIfuQ9dx4XZaAKMcvzU5GYHVg56rM@I2R7gi/VAn/61xTwjsBsmIS5tGBOzC@1rL10fMhdxwHeMqbFhKqK1QdL/Ite1fcWyu6b3ihb9Yu5NKu0qQvfMOekWmzsMH4PStNfjIjGux62MkZUdG3/iug6/E7fNwUN9eDVXgamAbh@@US7jQfyVdYG1@tlqVR@f8FMiZp/bxdhUV8/suja/X3EmybH4mQDDs0xfeYBmFiismGcSSF/@lTykdCUPWapGIMmeGD5t0q9XNZYg1fkXOAI0MryeizthgeOK0zkx2wjXsOnobD8/ONAFws@BYxm9WWCv9Dq07HF3TLeNCkOsNZ@aXXwrqEsGRabG/HJj8pWhwJpC7ERXZIMgZFc4qIss9QS0kfT109aKHrVKVWtCN@LUG7fL6bCO5Fhm742Bq2Yu0Wu5Nr0SD3VWHpFzw1p1bBjRKrJi0Mv2a0fS6tE1EGhsU5qOPND5lelVy9uhpZc1@yGzsYmbzKu7MBtFV9cfUWXd9fvpEXP1TCkwNwi8JDI9yOVDaX@j5Ing4f/x7Y8VmIQ7xXxo/QRY1/U7@ID8zHOCx4f0wCeuPx1Y88eAN74FsImdYLUKkAUefGSga2dTJaD1nJnNVx@GsXNX4z6pYxIZhJYkm9j11JRM50QiW3TzyzVy@Utfyj4aEJ6afSkwxYA7DdKD8P2vKFnwXLOBGueNeNhTVThh58V8cPxzHXFPQ84A8pY7lSY@PZWJ/@T@g8dH8sRX185P@yN8O@KSHLdi20Er52JLUq8ML7bfyY@j9S1/qtx@pkoHD@7LmGADvfmOhgQP3JlbeWxc9wwNySrGRi0IY83pegHx3tHDB5nlK5osdTDy3LGZjkcfPHuWxTdNPn62Njqe@y6MjoE735j9/qGqptd03@cO7Q5u4p5rStoE6cgEbRQ64z1uGuZa4arnTsz@0WJifgKTJ3Jw/wOLL26s5CPjxBriKGSVjYSigcoqcjGfjp3MBmXb9KLnpvY8tibILXv0UPhj43EUlBx0xdPXSw9X7fhflGJYLjiJ8MUyqbnLvTVuylgx/L8rYqqqbqLzM2MA7coKGxtrNcG6/WHbPfmArWQzUF6kKEiaQq@SrGvPkZekMbBuBW@4PB8EgrO78RjMVQCi4OLaAX9qOgvDkWgv6yrxogq58VDblUm@Zn7AhlR0wucE7aWv3eOLjtSzVI@c6WsKPvJiWQ4Obt@/LsPTgJZXp/ro0XP2xPDRDsrVCeMYmx@A8VIyeiXhuhUa4du4ndr3AJR2JbzhZP14rrJnhtd3ncX8@k04egcVp3aybxzBQh8lMm1rbq2bq3p8XevJ@mNG15XNX@JwFytycNw@TgDo/bf@harmcmT9CJ9qjnuvaZlwgLMUuowFmtSLRx3dj1hDD@UWGQLSa7XRB@Ycj6Pw1eB1Sv3a@a14xdxXSm@eTq6KK18Rl7@ivEtxGMh0OadeAbBwRRwryFH0A9c@HbnygeGZ/przx2sRuqoilSsqUolx58BgO20sBu7NIj6@uhA81vbWI3Pq5Scjt2vl19Zhf4B2LtlDtNd@OT44TmF4dLxl6AavfHD/@vJOZ@bagh4ab9ZHEKc5XhsFTNAczeiViMvRqxukXZB5TWdocROP7LY7PSTfFYpZ9Mbz@rMI1uTObLIZY@CN@FWMi@x8JeGnoDO7pz67ja/GLcX0Nbo/no9bH75JpmXRwiBaOr13tB/2rsfPFC1W4hKLz56sBOPLo9PHz2Jhnjmfb1J6pfkmHXJtzLLUR0f5lWJ3Gy9O1hBr8/tGIG4AP46eG@Ugzuw@fnaZJaD6NpqO7TDmY8NZrpiuNFjfndKbhmsjnyzmdIxybUuP@Cm2dXFeb03wimIPE7JlQdm@0umgOaZOZ1OvPDI/o70HEIPYlIslHGhgeMmc50chhpRl40B1j5fCzwq6zyYjy5mvjRpvykOnSFOv/PXDYJ89s91T9iCyKrSJPWjrgRsnprOJOa17WVGq6FdLYfoFkWpTu/APqASPTU1ye5OgdoFn4IGIq7gJ5n/aU@6Gnk@09LXpP34WJr8@7YHt4vp935qNr09MYDOZ6xN6V7C/iwCt65Ph90aOR67nXJ807E7V6m3zA5HY@uCU40XP/QAcuoPB9YkOfff6RA9n9tRCnWV90kfuzEYLAuviDr3h2vDGbqPVkqvypkg06O6PvPTmeDwX6c580IGsiHlGGaVX1nQlMOwz8TC0L286suOmL8D92GVfQUvya0jx5gPb6OO7m9KtbtjMcIuf3gheOjcd6p0s9GsH@RtrSJ4PGXSONb4y7dLk333PdbgvvWl6XJr/W1PSPcO2rmVo4YEH7ZqjDzih8Xh2ol/PtUBAuLu5zT5ZzJfq5mrtbW50Yl3cgQZEGfZ66fAjSHg0XdVji378/Jnpb172o9n/q4djo@dTR@PWBmCyin8sw88Gtsa4dQ5uE8GXwy@apFIO9On06ufj4gYe0KR8ahtNKm@TMQdI@/Yt2woMKECEGJpkCExGoOVVy5mZaPOBf1RqWt@GYup1tVBhe/i9tipTc1Qmfoqywg1choU12fZZYA6hWlXP2VadiVWRBQYpInv13OY6AEZr0VApJh2rbHsKMduhMQVGnw9ibxmtAUs9NMoLPlmJm5WpBeYmAKftsyf3nxw@O9o/ev6smWufB@Yowlo4DpQWGr25ofdFqHxAN9At@RcYyAyKDcXRp41w7dgP68Xwc2mrVauvVG1ZKXEP82yfOY6ikEUORToH/CSRl0axKCFBEIcd1pgaKDDGUuXGMcjGB7QRBy1SmdBoVZZbV/DEAD1p2wniL35dkGLxK5RV/A4lFhwYzYcOPnTdflCib7Lrr7DEu/v3Hzx/eshCBJe95tTqT0f1SoF/U4FbCYJ2Glh0RLnOkkGWJLRVvZ68mwTCJOUkq5INFfqeAXR0SBZSB62vBLl3WGqb4AMFk1GjKP/168p5Usa3bdKQNhkilYRioc9TR9na2mJH0EnYnaf3Pzl8yhD/wzsUjCRCEOwIDTj86Y/6/ItAoYG18Auc3piUGjJQJcSNuISWTZbGV5DmNHYnm7/DSV/gIRMn0ad/om@XCQJ9GQr67SmZZ71gNzNNpuz4d0MDs6ZhQdSFwq@I4MYumihFdmn5FhpYQRwGaDF0tbPjWVAy1CuzffzIKH7K1KDPUwHqM2fKrfIFtrkS0NPkiOdk2TYhyz9mJcYSJne3oLN3TdB3me9YMONOq@wV9ETcPK1yAzyS1EheyhKCrpJLQh0plvCSiVFfaXnK@1/5Z8qwxsA9Bfe3A/c8dxt8vxT4BuD@Ze5@oWBHu2ySdIlLHCG0ZBzUgCMS0R9pH/u2qsONHi0Jh5ZTQ8bKrDE00wlRHZPzEvhdAn68hJNqfgKNBt0NWiwwdsTLM712Ck0pVxUFuxSuwcgkOJhzfu77gknlYqGYVxVAUjoJAdI3UIZo0IIDTKerMEyEE2tSfwl6/e7uLhNxIdasF2u8ZZVt54UuvowQ3Ya0AkzUgFyTQR7IsswBcY0gG8w@GTWNWZF7JdUkMq6@C9MSxeP0hX4nIITIUkAsTiMTP6oxx8/wTkE9CUyDd/HDtbHvY20HgCQV5iRypUUhMBP0yJ1C94FBuvwCHjcThO898CkQDd76/OPUZJEb@6N8eWQtrVuEH@IKxpqMPICD0nMXZ9N424qfIohnCKIqruu@zResNW05bYX3TQbd9AdrOrMD7l9Uhhv6LK/3/mVjyKmLpoyRWOzWM8fFFee7UBmW0hRNV9RielmlfH5tlYIaBcVAddDi2lsoDtgUsIyeab1yJ/7@weH9jx8/eXbJ4C@lTF5MBny/sZtpSXK22Y4cyXi1Vpvk9l3l2cPbd8OGWCJdjHFjYPxBTdSrarLcSEKQyxcTL1ZtHYYXa7cZ40@56ZKL@OraVahRpkt4qLkvUC69HCTdpVd8LxaulddRq1C4CqUlPCUG@oDbZ7iEaip9dt5sg7rnJJKXe8KagfAiIe/gIABXy9/ZVrCzX64cViz6bPwRfojTj49Fff1YFLd1tCeJ5mGm7vHS4mYQEIuI1TcsBlikICth0o2j7zEX0pd2YTX@WXtuiDJuZi@GcDF3FcVjoKiqION4yEWWVq0Dg84jUMVsqyuE5g25YefQ/mxk05mbJkylheDzTLzgFH/nhs2rc5lOAqfSyO0IVpZdZSM6hJcWYECjdPdkBirhE3fCP9dBJ77umKHrqQvs986MrxCb7OPZGNIN6PHUpN134NwSZAZKJiNUuSwFXCIwET3PoBFuKK@JhqKDisvjfiE1T8sjc963hsDbU@kscLQbqtpmkRlprDSZjXaSIrXZshWuHIofodWNONm/kC3x@RIBo2nIltM356nkaTJdbUP5GJ48/fQkmRbX9SWyaR4Y@e5fNG4eoV9Sr@YkxjQYnaHl8HXcolK5zCUg7CJgbmQz/FZgpSKPfIG@/VpHyf3Z1HsAThAjUoOxMWGpmcMNlMqMvKlWysmS5UapwY0fOyyTIYUKHhQhM8o5IBefv1OGs2AppY6fB4ZQ3@nj4401YU1VltvgpkLSbBu/4XkAEhea7E0LoARDliqBrWMXAjUDMOKDROYdHPJgPKSFB5l5XRNNnzSkTUoXaUK1Zo2bLPZN1lXJUaxUqkGDrnLFCoPed5kdygqAvcTnQrkeqBvYLgOagforC4klI7/M8RJUboIjci8wegboJGIGy0NbaAxgLc2J90Ye/lKHDowVkA@q1edHdzvltCKyyHja0LP6uInOP/sRqXjBh9pgmCorSZM1rtF9hNnQTG2HW2dDa6l3acCIF1hqIk6GwNR3qCz7y76pqlf2@iBj0AqQMo8TQPCSeScEh6aFw8WoNXHrmf1Pf5pAYSO1rarHHe8kkyzkanBTawVWYDe2W5K03czVb20boEVNX89boJMrO/kT885o0L8/VFqiyHSWV5Sds7Oz5N2dJ9aLAitKfUsrvp4vzvWi/np@rqvl18cTtdiUX8/bYrmePW63mm325Mln7zrv0uL8ZPFaZK0U6JoHj0U1LyaqFXa2V9QTxxX8eDmoN8fsDVzHA4b/5H7Tj7kNdHcHoMImRZZotYDiqlgSFaWZbMM/qfsv4eKKf7MhN@S99rt36aZhTOcLZlnWxO/34eeOQILU0s8Y6Ms3gdPzDApr0ZM0KLgK4zkwu31zOJwdGgtrdnd6Sy7JZVmLrS7sPvzap8FV@/T5c8aes@fP3zzdsBbRzmRSktQk9/xCXLVjFBL4@fE//fHWefbsSWf3T78xVswtfDzGx7fPH6L7mVq4sbV14/btfD6raRp3P/nak5/f39/P38kWnjQLe3kpt7X7J3@8taVpu5qy1fZ9tZ1sHh9/Jmq5vCj/6Q@TnSdPvur7Df3/@Pq7hoq3EtxOWAn4BFw6U8GJ9zL8VJSxPvRKvElAL1cTC/rrJMLwsy2mNvZK/@27j18npomGpnzqwXOaeJ0olhPcCQ7w6aHvJNFI7GKy4nliodTrdXCW/tu/h/yNjwEOxix24dYohLCKi0RDqlOWt4lGERyqpkG5/9fXvx7DkLOJOolx4XWLNeES8yVN3GvDtUPXroBGaaWcooTpnOloarpMLd9Ub6LHAg88HBO/7mFOWwm1nGePb0HKp81MJtOWOxJc8gtaJFJUVWup6k1gB9KNnXpd2mHc7K6uF27ipwPStKQ1dGHGNG9@unIlPv17udaCqf09AH4qJIpbt17eaTSgdnpD32lk6AqGFI2uUll03Vsiy7KXSVBGmu2XrPYAoxpirqyJ2Wz2VocPjTlSTZqHQySBF78nElEIDl52IayB477NonCei13Oy@Kg16ZLHOL1Z//rn33vz75Lf9@j339C@71O3xooO5DoBAZHA65b1Wqv0RAbnnjWQn8DelSuWq6Wlc55K7XTbLSfMjX30dtkQU8@YzgPqFhGK91qUv4GFdsIikd/I7EMbvCQRjwsiOCJKQCeAaVYYpVq5I6oxtiFdDDJBm86SM2TRltC0aguNdVioS3xXM1b0DiiVqqInXZC2l4A39HaDa2gPWa3Gvxio22fuYiNrhXDigT4NpZ1W8YsfY14UKIRZmss03zRdAFOFSHRbCptk2aGRojora3qVrlarGpKp7H5qi1z4EVJTdN84idOEtFVY0E/DOmZiHpmLOxFvCWiZmFhB2Yrea9JB20FLAJGBv@PX1p0MWouvaiKtcCldURWg/6h6ZI27Ig5VYwGGy30w7UFf/QPV@TF@xaFBMGU5PK1xarqjqYrhRvFQw0n2muuON4CTBis1@123/S6IH4YRtfoGerUmBlzY2FMu7PuvDvtzXqMjxm2rL2nuwW37IZeWUroBXU7cROrpGsVrYyfftTLZb2i6SVVLxX1Uk4rF/RyRS/l9VIJAOolTa9U8pqmF0t6sawXi3qxAuEapClCGh0hlAp6RRcS75pb7Clna22WCa9W5trruSx3Aic5XPxJkjtPCIl/gKuhairbgakvBzeQ98gJ6jj@qarAEiDDnbXf7TTf7cCIb2R2idu2G1KAJTzkzq12Rjo/b4K7Vgv@dxuRs0YXd0Hl2ueZzO6LBog2LxrNDIB8EYCUJUZA5U6DtXcpKiotKC6I322DdCRldpu7dfeAfjKNOakNIHdX0Lx1KyOD6xbkbGzD2E5nMtuStIUTbjOYdiBxu5EJ6wOQ2imWzLvJonuLQeV/xh8okcA/znfPG@fN3fPz3V3436X7efCE0PPdS//0WF4b0izj28h7Wk2l0VJaAf9pg19WGhgiKy1wNOAJ6Zq6Vm7jjIfyi9z@x/kvZ5f3KARRbsuAtZDYYTsJtE@rJ3aExMv3n//P@Gu9//z3UBZl8GdWhcQZcgplBzXZCldo4cachw57yC8H3PgLvRiCAY2HGOjwm4ObXYryUmZVvp@QUsvFtIxTescddNDkjcxeQtIV1opclIlauSh2MupCY4ldsVgiFvpzl65kMvlPXmqVUpIvAqHNlpe@7z@MYbnEExLXtJwqqW8b/LMk/AtSP7fu@ic/t@kSEm8rzKwCfVKME0ZIQD9KKIokNYREY3eML/XgNoyEGu9J/TPp@b6ESzTGlDbZenz5oX7/sF6pNFD/Mbef0NjZubMDdxX@D7egFqw1gKStQb03Btm6NdALWgs/YZGQuq/x78Eb/GNHPfx7@hr/2NEb/Hs6xT/2sIt/R6/xb7@Lf0dj/Lv9Gv8evsG/50P8a31J19WauH1GhMmoFfV8ey4SgWowYzVaX5p6iyp9j03U9jRQWINFrJSer6QTrS@Z8545mVaD1UZ8w8rsTWtGvVLr1rUgaXA8HGNkyw8/eB8sLlY1lsZlUL1ScD0JzzLCDQIyekV1veRPvvONbyTr9aSUpE9p5SFM6mKiLiUCL@TMc0zwE8WAHzS37ydrt5JfatICQ6HSbmJkGyKERJ1tq9tqzs71cmpX7YLDYjmP5Ua5kdpXSRHLmSy3yC1YbuyqfXCZ8JcDl5UbsNyQ5ZycA8kgFlzTTm6KrgE8hvA3AEAe/Fl4TL6r5noMCrJRFKWvBqsdzJl722kJTZZk4ksTNGlZlXNy0Wrjh86a4suXLWWnrVXKTMZuLXeaL1vJttgS8eMXWiXPugtzq/VSBIEjJ/LujyEs4fugntcSSqulcMIDuaglz887ncNHdzodBWfCFjMbmVsZYPC3btWB4QePvUSjtteq0nwRzhkJZXev1dAldBczMBtoGJb5gtcSIjwbW1Tz9svTl6DQpE5RrTk9gcdp6Pi0BbcOV3goWjn9tBXzkkNRTk956jUQVhxLQSb@D/rgP9S/9Y/r/@FzlmapZjudOjvfTdGVxr90@uz87Dy4N9KpVOBJ7cIfBoAfs5ydN9BJic7A1Uyl2@nzcx4G91R6lwNsQDG7Dcq7THfGElGJVCq/pf5@n1BycLWSNTavk76fz@m17fnbt1z5L@RoKCSANUXHflqteS6XBkYVfJgHN7GNt3S2Il2jr7Jud5tq@09@SB9f2ktTokK@VlN3GPdoea1Wy4e@UrlWK4ee7VSqcvlq5PbUImhF@Xw6XauBZy8EmwMv5G2ydxlWZy24t2/e5IWUtaAWAFPPFzM5PG5Vq4UlFaBY0zd6Adc@u/@YvlsEvKKQYMgSglMnqRx99wx5eVKsijdvpvomvk7R39tP37ypVXJv30YhkwkEqStBnU7f8jodDNffvhU7Ih3UqRTAnyu/favmKhk1mXa91CP8KCsUlZJUdkNrUKkV4NNavgTRAQKF3d1ivtEo5iGkWE5CG9Y4k64lxWRNTJxRFdRyiXMwkYITMKBhfvTPzhPUhixfSKeA@aVBcjxP4J@HfJLPT4VCupbP5RJn5yJPrFYqPHWa5YupcqYS/NW30qwB0hH/QxFPz@R3Sju3QFjGP3@@7kJWWjsz6@p5/cys4lL/eQ1meN8F2QYt/pg3b@oVIEs5V2sJnc6d/aP9TqcOUxBKWHDDQGLKAhpC8pLV2i1qTbVcYIlkjQdKSeDkrAyUVbSdglpGYgjWAC14gZggcFVti20JGj3xJlS4NLUFgaD5rPI9oQ8X67MuG@LFhqhFMovZdDGb8Xi693pRIpdfQWzkpbykaIYhZnQJwbDTea@EiffJg/2Dw6OstiuxhHZ3/yCrPXt@O6Git7D0U7SO/qeH@3ceP4cMTx4c7j87/Oj@J4fPn0C4z06XVzQphFNDNEXEXGv8p@xT4ZX3xjBNw5yZZud0Njt9zV5ZVseClrRnUCl36DHf7EBdJsayXjX49SzfePXK8CZ0sfc/@Nb7H/x373/7O@9/@1vvf/t7P/n8e9@C34/g9x3@/M6/qxTw/pPP/8XvvP@t34bA/wS/P4Tfj3/y@a9/nf/I/0fw@y@xsD8KfrF0/CcArF/6yeff/eFPPv/l78PvXwW/71/@/cqP1/@@983NP8z33d@5Os13/j38fpfDCtN@57d4GD4vpf8tnu6Xv//@1/4D//@T4A@dv/3@1/4Ib4Hnn3//T/7L@2/8R00r/8m/ff/N777/5jfef/Pb77/5T7X3v/5v1Vz89jvvv/f7f/kHv/uXf/A/0v@P6P67H/L//vv//M//lz//3/78D4Lfj@H3H8D14z//jzBI/@b3f4D/3/39v/nDH@D///Sv/@b3f/VvfunfkOM3uOP//lf/jt//6lf@81//5rf/8sdf/@tf/fFf/8bv/@X//sv/56//57/673/vr/7ZNzDwN378l3/4S3/xjW/9xTf/5V984/MN929def/8A8I//wcI@XA8PwTOh9Tri4Z8/jPh83ehxrIU6CfQu3/x/a//AnTwX2Ps/bd@hC/Kwm/D/480ldL8iPv@f@DQLtcZY3Lggt@vvv/Wd5BE/wOQCP4jen078qzEcM@3lx4g62@uyfSLP/n8X/6QfAmz2qB9JJy4y1o5swPKzU6lEkzewRYTZPmFVWgRgKCkbyOHWon7NvK29z/4@vsf/tP3P/iN9z/4JZy5pXwlu5@V1Gv25yBh4QPSYcLih6TDhJ9B@Z0Mrc9Jmc/At/VZoaw7jlP77LPPhM5bBd/IvvWWfQZ/7LPwYjwK39gOosI4DMdXuBmEN1@@bOOmbixMUTlwRePPIArP3ENJknYjs6eoGo8y3yrbPBerQYBe1lsx1JXBYKcKfwxu1erOWVbaa4HQR1nPBTOskhpA3VKYamT1Hd2AhEqep2NV51YunyntGAZosRmEmyH5ZyeUxwo6m2eCIufBxi@GQ6L5DjnnjK/mzyl6Lsxpfxj@S4yVmc6Yw/9rAsuQuEQXfrk2dJIjyBfuLZNTKEAxmeVeAQmIjEtoOzyEdsyp3HyFYQ3m88wcNG9wQAkZiLoNkn@9nsGMdY4ieHllGmVGqGQydag35uZ5sp0ygpjfJiiQs555yjo79TnPmEF4jZAcGQGDnoqqJmbK9TtQYH1@hyEsBE5gX76sN8r1eQPBvePUycwztwknBFbPzBvvwF8nmJBPSNx5B6iU65lMo4wFYiV582Q7vJEKVDmqe4ZlgjaAJ774sHeLsRuiWhb5NskWEoynxntmmRoTQnKIb2V2gurQf@ik3w4RfIuKCkphPH6P5OM9LjJjAoArSbIsM/jhSYQ9dgui5xxUhoqFR4ZDyFCPoB4QBTBcS8oIGWrfDHmg/ER95wtfCAwrs729LSQaoi4@lol0isK84yq9BYIHI1GtqTKxWBEx2KRXYkJcIH@Nyt9O4sZiknHA7EaG/27d2mE3oJr0XIYJTMrobt5NcCi7mYyoAfyGmxFegC4kQD8lQG8FeV6njcyMkM0yJtcTGMceP34cIEEBL@pCBrq5pqvox/202WyWgByynJWz2eAp05MC5MAhU2zwlLeRuKeeNTWZpuVroLLVGAaxuH6lgraNge/evYNWoZNm1fug5bLg0JmWL1MkBHCDWLa9CN@d0vIVgS8CMLWYZyxFC8JwpRm@JJSCjpQW@BsKHI3wSiW1cjlJKYH@cmonPIVYVJED8Lex6P1oViiteAGbuBdX9vjyMe6mR69BcfxS5UI6jDx4zA4eP3x4@Oho0m4zAb@OO5uanYnn9kzfT2Hc/qM7/GUWrVJMJ5pNpMpRVUOOJBxWc9hRM/fvPL3/rMo4lYI2S1E9arQRHdClogqJyeTT3URwaEvET5y64jO8V5ekSGkV4JbpRENI9ExUgaDz4T/8asJDf3jbnbNULiuKWbWI6mgaN1QBj593ZwwNcHNrXTAI8RUXeXeXKCA0zqTY/g0GNNhTTeAOSSUH0yvl0FHiDrVUxAT8YCTThcazwyMAffSYqVpOFhqfsbmMqEnnQsOu26YznI628YSh2MqJsdpvN3NZ/NN0He5qvphVC6X21pZ9JmFBLeoPZ3hU9By8ZxJW@MtwMeHLAvsyBMEFZeD5TxYsh99/XAtOQKJRzBQ/BimqBRjBaQGX9Dk4YRK/ajBwVnfEhMTW1742ZY3G4aM70v27qNTPRyw8BChZfXkkU4fozzyTYoeM9a1PLPzKrdy3/IltLGBUAjUS5@fnA4B0/y7TGhp5eY4@3s97FNIF9/ncEBJOtVp/p@ZLwtP9avWdrmkCBAg7Cp4y3IKuQkc0dhT@V/OhEF0vK8AEVVGEh67rAnV0oWoKjA7kvMvV6xLvrXpepfM4An44yZjXlzvrQdr5jWVaPcfTYgxEsOHUY7kwrsTjAl9RIB8QDY8g4nFyIVwBy928qeOijJ7PRasvVGN2Dm2zred1pDi@4tVO5EvBbpEoiu2EYJtT1q@DO9GCW42PNzUhMvQhP9LLOSHRTMDoE5rtZv3//b92U2jP//H@A1mazbowByYW/wXBmIaebOVPEB66j5f/jx@P494r/8eP3YeP3bEL/zBLPRRCHkX/tdqK9@r/gLchD6nVhP8PXsEW5W5gmrtBB2ibaiXfPoSR0mTt3dBqdwPaY5fbM2doLq0uTs05fj6Bh4kN37QHMr55Vxd3Jw09p4m7wfdBGmHGRr/ed3szPOpU68uW45gevt7MM@TzYs110NJuPdwHhOkkfSYM66dkgkUw60MZjbd5jmELfbnr9heyP13Y@A6b7Xr1JKggyTBiCd0E2RQXYfd0PV@FKskTd7InaIVSpqnmQKjAn1rOatktc69Uqvblnm0a3l6hWihn@/h6XLBLu1fIVYfyZw8f3JtOJ09NemduL1@BDGjuFA0T7pWrhQJ0VlHMNKmYdjPXlvm8Im1tATM2jb4ET9zE9SWt3IbMfcur15PJPV3VJLWq58rnwpJwQPOR2sjn8rsKPEFfUnBzGOY8oCkSWd1VJth84IQkBji74CzsKl1wWuCs7CoWOGcNXc3tKjPeikizhoDIZJBWWWzJ7Eg9C@aDquM6MPVUs0bWOiPSVgeDwfnOWWbpEYwzifuA6OeSke2eRd6aFEtXZbOsZC0jIcQYQBueBXveVVErlMVas7b0l4pirX0u3BqbfcvA9@9aubPLuYowRXOoCSioxYTzque602rXHLieuUyoq8UwIUfocoK8eB4V18phiWeXiyvGEs3PLkPJF8TzKFeIlnB@Do3J6Q3C1osXQmLn6Sd6owEd4yxf0vKFfEHTi8VCSQOxopIvgtqeU3PFXEHTYBTmK@VK6RxGgaK8S9BHbdnBWTg6qvRZn5RR5Xapm22WfvfIss/KusTHcSpdg/kr8U5I3Hj6idZobF5CSIEY9okmNep6oQIuHV2aLiAP1jRJ0yVdlVQd/69xaPj/4ek1@NfwDrl0TThCa3WPQDwC4c9hD9Dq1dRlRy5@93DIbpu9DSkORga9HnDgub7/d0hz23COedQdi5uIj6LuGfjxV39sTUcbUjyfjNHQnen9g0E4HHcBQeSePMFtuHm2665LUGLPn2yo5cPooyxADP5VFkj@9P5H945iz6PD/YN7QpHdfvzozoVHIUhUYA8O7x5F3hKPDbMWIhA/f/jgwUVv8Mg/fv50MHM9/Al3Hz/PL29REL59LuThWk0UBROQ4IZeUjVAcgRdvlAKHaqA7yzdzFfYzcBZKC6dOXR@yl@tt/zoHRpuZaEqHIXv2xsMGXPXZD1uzxAXfMjWcKAMqqWKIEyY456yUo71Xds2POYOBlsQODLw3WETVRzbxp6IRZ@6nt0/tfrmFogzUEYFNMUBISHcAyDjWY9M5YDQipbrYRJ0GG6hdu2ZyWYTtjEQHhiETs8ajmDKPnXDBELXMBj8vugF@c34Nb06YMrLoLBLMfbl5EJCqCTKonggiveMqVHzzNKLXLX6xIOp2x@ajcM5dFcYPIa3yJazujgV77Kq82JHG@J@nO1OUCH1J82dGUjlW1ugVe@1/uo3f/S3f/yrWit3kCvgWuLu3sMHeW0BIoaq1Lr1d6Djj7tvGy/YXt69xRhK8qjgyZ1EFVgfaDOMFJZAqZFJEdYq5UK5omvlbLlSzhfUYqGQVbWsWiqXKpA3p5bVYrlQUbPlfAWEmnwFYgugkXKVSAl1IGWnCmCdnj3rm7ukS8sjUJr5ljp7kzLSLGFE/hkTTcgjCrjOMSU7DTtWHaZOpuaYXmIA0WA9lrh79yB3964o3kYPnio6yIliHz2Fci5Xui2KJsUclFFAE12ep4z2gsUp9@Ryt6EJZhwAfmpHFEfoOSziSrEoWug52L97F8sZoEfD/JDsmMdwjx16SpDMQQ9oagTgdQQNku3zcvKE6CF6sEiMuctjDiBOFD8K0cGYpzwZB3AvrOn@vije5579fYw5oGoXOKJfQc8@XaLogQeGhigOwTH0YFCKYhecOEBEsQeu3sKAsDG48GssztQQxQUnDxJIFOeU2ugdi2InDMdiPgmwKSB1q@RRea1vkaeCf6KohUhjMj3y6KKYjzx5qNu9e58Yo2nfHPJr4fFnD2p6755uWPPZ4d3uRx91h8Out9g//OgpRh0c3AM5ZDHzusNukLHbgcuFXAf3NON4vLh4Qa3vdzpVw14b9ZVOJ284F6I6i46JGEKu14BZcA2xoHHnAKIO7nVuGeuORxDADvKGMTy7eN0ew/O20eVR4UVR9Jx3u2INu7@itFICqh94zgGH4zHwWic7NnqeW0P/vM5yWRRpFs1irl2jCDYGNSJXO8f4QQrvBi4vps8WzXk9167P66XgPOIgJbbmWsESs1vjPbVSqG4Ze6qWz8yraCrGHSRZUlL3WEq9ufOGpR6l9zRQKbbE1t6eJDbV9l6x9ALZTxVve5paruZzGktzr16qQp5cMscY3tLNUnuvVKguM5dKGUPRqqUSiG1AnylM/l1c0OuwVOrUNI7TaUSdVo2gPlRxtqBKW7VBap6d1zmSbJGuzetqjX@SgOUuQEul@vj9m1kPzZ4zDnQIAOd7uSqerEmJaqUsAg6KkkqnIx6ogGu5BPfpV4@Oj44@IwmxESxpPfFMZGa1wPvRvQP5/uPQh9@uke@i5Op68gEysZUYLsKGQUegj8j3YM4FbTEMwzd0PdeWD@lUKYi/YURoPk8O7MjLR/dW4Dwbuae8ZDRwUiNjxE7PZPhpH6vPjHoDXEafpQgrZqRPabbvNBr1Tn1MNkCgimGurzD67s0SzH2f4x6ZXaHsZ/jWahDRqefOYbKZJ@YAp1Nnkvpy7PZfaplerY9f9Lldv42Zax14dmtm3fQ81xNB1RNrgz2nPnN8Y2A@MT00KHT/8TbIHvgqa2rAzPQ2ax1i6gNUWc6lhsecJWaPZuOUITW66dUgXNiNApA4qa@GlT6jt6s7dVE8rw3qLPUCkr4Gv7fNUn35dnovXwM63WadNATlXg5eDpjGivkaaSYphAUji@iD9TZYut74Cjw47ONqFbAJGvoYoGJhANjqUwSknljntV7dZimJzVmaiJSvDetNzP4Wb7sSTO2S1HzbFhqS9KnQgOFbWySMuj/r0sfgWK6rarlibQ5hailfG0HzGi/mNa8@mXlmzQZvsMrLXyQ3akBUoB2AefM29f4Xvp7elQp1HlYjUG9RJujInfq85qB5aegYdb0OEZlmPpctlEFcKJSyIAJoxaxazOrZfFYqYSjM/9lCFgJBJQJxJGWnRMbEbG6ek9WsaqrZVO6l1X@Zzh6nQMohorF0duoeOrMxgxBoKuyb5IUnkCej7digqvVdZuxK1FmBa9SwYkD1EZtY2RGCemoaNuVIpyWm76Ts7RSm2T6aTQ6b7Wr1cD75KkSlpNd7xUwpl3mTTtdSW@m6b74WGjWhgQyGaj3Zgp4bLIAzfzZuQiuDSy1p1Wazi1Us5bJ6TofaWZ23w12xIbazua2iCk10zohtMM434mvCKAAtwyYdFNVtE5pOrWg1QaYFWr2sSRWlsFPI8UVinlOYBAwOKclSLTE0mpBKJktaMplO1nDna0sMdi6ApxE/SwKDTd5U90SQzcSqWNEwwZI50nvxuRA7kM7OBZQjWR404TPh/Ox8tyF8SXiGbzvvai/wr/Ti4f5j/PsSBFXAW37x8Pnj54/vCkyhE80gP9a2anKtUwOPJDduCYkqY8BJW4FFN2WLsS96Vjqz23jBny18yQbgCvTJiCZr0xlG00I1j32C1kL2WBLqYHjjpqbp7aZWgqkQuGmYVNPUGmDRSeBrPHIDGmN@BvjtZhr4ou1X2GJhZKRwbeBmtTHMbOe0ReKkIxYrOn9PtKHmjtlW8uYOA@lGYomT462GtpNJPqnqmeSdpJ5PnKRa242MukgqbCejLQZ4/AK38ZUkpNPMnRv6TvJ5ploeZqtqBu8a3KtJJm0lbnWyt9IVX6AmYYkLixX79f3h0/1a6DtolLVF8IJw4kVHLJcCFFvbQDIt82I1dwPm3xe4j9IS8OWPZOIsyRLJ8@R5M9kWErfoNWSNv4bMEtGLyHgAItgW1PNFlk5U0oGvVEn4qWhP7kvJW4kkbn1Vff9dgjpV@G7nV15q0J8TjhsGgP6HC28w3xYKuOuTUF5O/K9pZf3h/cfOHe@uKSRaW2@3XNytC5eZ4XrnfPxVxiZA4iRr1RPzej54l0JtNCR1V0PDiyVWhSlloBal3NsGHzQNiihqEPP@F76fn@@CfsS0nAp@TStktEZD3QFZJTF5//nvoQmts8NP9h@wJO7c/O0f/1Ar/e0f/2s6r5k8p90cTS8lICU61WIpcXY2OTs7h4vHFRLtxKVjKm2gj6IaldKODLVRygY4OkqC0xFkqpKaTvhSIjijWyxIqZSqaOkdvZxLQ8zbwEReSsuVwRtufVKQWCyI6cThU6ugqbd296Bme3peq21BW6rRK@Us@ts1/Qo0Tvnhy7eMgafX6A@HlkYuRWHVd9LuOybtsne46/hO2mIv6w08ZqPii@jhXtsOvuCKW9nJRkbZSTLQxVijeV47b2dos4602hc7TusCHVpb@PbUatCOA3/mjk9/pkleCvDBG/rMnVe@mNpJK0q/TyYbcSdUkhoJPkI6Jis0oKvsKIDlTrj1xv8kqZV@/wu/rmnFv/3jX3nbedv5TAM9tlIpqlripz/dnTkz3@w3fgoZrzCYFOqiJIGiZSN0RDos48ZMrSBX5JB7oD7PHJTXefpQo0UdloFwYw0ds08arXCCAhm1aIfb7OynKNkO2lPJkrxPNvLSNUEIZWEuz3vDXpZgsB20vd5sp4Uz4csYBfM9A52gJnx5CQoCxjDDu72Ob8@8Cb11lqJ8ajvLbkIWKOHLaA91i@zABJOFBFxT2bmclaPsE9VIeGNj0/fRuirMc8KXIUvwgQp7wSYGmizClJYDs5OMSQhPiug3oew2lG3zDB0KTVHteYIs49jxTA6I@cKXQV4hKlggxjBrFxLUgJ18GQgAdUgFgK0222V6mp1ZmUxtabr1nEGj41tYRmguRcBsCK2P5nnCzDVMB0GgXuAn0bFfBC0MUmQsMATCYfADKnVQUDA7@VAyJHtGHwwKYJHtwBRVjd28ucSqXrf6aUY1QvjH1gTX4qgdnPW4ArBQ07vRr4pZhkZxa2Fo1O2A4hlCF3qdxK3h1mJZmYjec0GA/w/utNgjLzQVRdSwAkF78VHRA5JBZiQ7b8Me260zVSulWYR8D3DvEVJktCJSX1vzG7L2WRh5Dhj@NBF@cBCY1VF8fTPotxft5TCQ5mf4tTe0msiZQWDnhttFRKZ3fxrmjnJBVSybUg8sDzQpOjkTmmRN6Woasy1N2BIe9PKJlmf4DkghjQ/KhakZPA00LRqUs0Um0XouNKg/cR2yRUq20vAVHOgRwKMCM44c7Zlzil8HDdqGMscx8smEI/Z8xJhsq7podIry4kmUrgc6d0ibLDOHMuuN@0yrsBR1NDI36UTg0pSJEO6CQI407trmGFB6Zpr07qdfVZQhCGmzLtncfGhBvxrdtWDmcXzlDiewcmodW8oRmumX3AG@IsotGCVQrsPhx4@yBPYtbdc9ZrZ1bPJl69SK/SefgUoCUnUWKLv8AWGrePxK07O4UKJmeSr4leBR4s5yNpZ3K7VIX37q6laqgy36lmYwC1rFNk8MJ0Zfut4KgS7uL/zQghzZQQO/HLFcM7AdVU@iVZjIKJoQ2MKrkxk2GbdDJikxIYY25NApTDzzhKFWLeAcA0yzF1pjwlEMtf0yTQA09mBkoWnZqVdFG2KAiddP9WDoBQzeYTeYrgmYkBv4C4zxAQxs@voqdIiDrFgPf9qHhpFpDwD5CozOcR/i0HpN0P0wf9i70U1mf5fdm20F4HDSobLqjA@L0FOIeXB0YH@mqm9BZBEwXIPJVkrMANiMmBY56Cj/xey8twvES6rsMqQsQwgBqQEKiQoGshy0HRr7jKcAEbcNn3/rKTA8e3p6KpM15JlnyaaPn7b0XcewlcnQAknYVabmeKKYPgxdz@opkxDu0iXxL9rKk9Fkb47ybL1yc8GfgjDw68GZtFRy4CdxcjzBLzcOx2Q5EU0W@tSh7lr01ddeKjgix/uf1s6ehf2viv1PKifPEQhjCGaeXWR7WQCW7faOs4PTfi2IOKEBCcChFc0wEG2Ue6Fn7IcuazKIUrhT5KNRVNc@pu1igCTyFeVl0byGYcpF6A38E2sOmRzzlO17nrFIUXwaU2MHTi1I7GELmPYpBpz4HYwzbjDbmjcX7ZXs8yg7TGrRCQwPzSIKZ1cD5dbTMX7O4@cQP@fx82WhYbHNeZuLZBh0jtXBXo/WdMOUCGYRpjnnlsaXMQQZ5HCmchCYcrESdg6/Xp1yh/TmPmjHetgxoE9MgOBmSmm@aDVbbcc3T3faGWUInV0kQkCLA@hmm2h62o/cSH37xJ64/kqQg0aUYVYK8Mag3ijoDbyvYB2jBqKOwellod3b4Tg4KsIFgqDCAAHlMIhE0WB/mrLStchcP0VCx2mKSxpzxJoBMm2SvoKoIAzEJU56Ttg4oHYMEIZHVQI0IYaFI4d/yDjkDp96LqQJ00r07dUx2l9MtpNAyQtDhfOaGjVSDCtJCtEEsqO4Wr9YlTAemqJ5ISpWzfOg/ePob31h9AcwLtZjTx2WTxg1IT5U8AAuiBDBcCGqskY91q6AgbJj2KYHM9chl0@D2RqK2fl/uvu29TZyJM1r8SlgSi5lWsmTbMs2ZapMSZTNLlvySLLdXlnFSpFJKcs8FZM6sGz3N7sX@wK79/sI@yrzDnO1T9EbfwSQieRJclXP9H5b3RYzE0AgEAgEAkAgomCWGVIPmhBdh6PmhWN1ftOV/uEryNlethyzwrhSoSaOKzIsZVwYkgrB42KRLjY2jKDLiwAhGMWZxQJd7MYudlOpiOBQN3OKXVtI3jCSN1JEct/MQfJUF6PVU91ML@ieU9JOYSGcJXglmUZJDRpkVeRfBTih/xW@YXFsoetMZA5zgeYhqNjgs@bpzNpPLKQtoTUBAIw4BYC0EP@yMypnJgVeKRe/xTJKSGlklLxpNhBZQQzGInhT/Kc7MZPxGpgU/uwazwM0drNrJ5lsibee8b@i/Mt65qP5V5r@WEznLKU/Fr2J//2HfDwFZa0BamkfpeIjCGSsZN71tONhW@dYVtVLWuCQVnd23VfODGWbvhcuddHCWad/Vuj6sLRBpHT5mh@MXbN@wOGNejHoj/xR/9GjsiyaQma7WfXLmiE87/URYNGKoUC6XqsfRL3VEXVqs3/eC6PAU3Bv@znQy45AB4vJ2HqyfuxHmYw2@pJlLEALX0HVbTTCXjhqNBxYXrrl@KYAG2KCPVdXM1j/0pNVnsSTBnowcPpnvwbNkXs7TAQE0cWOw@Zn52CgE@E4papIhjVJ/6fUC9JgVNRPVo4cbACq9NnI4bA6F/1u/5y0vssojx3YzAT4egIbCPmDAePiKR9L2rIVFoZHidP0fFcX/em7i6qf1h3fjcuvpwGkiOGp4SSNQdnhjOoac6uTYqa@o@/H98jG92gxvrwKn8RZluYVSfy@qh86CQTKmKDx8HY00HSSW60pdFKoxJ@hV0mBO6PYYku2FjCtUtaqzp5vE3948VtEbzHi7@fRf3EHmuK1u3afT8NeHY1J3nRhVS1OjyJzButQ9roL2TNdXczau3esi/IiHPkeVAhSY1lw9eAnnQYmAphFcawfA/gWnofx2BTfs0VZRRJn4DS88tTn9fldtNtoBR1/HLQcndOz4JoWH9KCjeXV3RoOQcdCry9rPYfmLjdOpWkcRJdM5Tks43tXrjufrSRLGHMP75QzhvX59EP6lGjGFl9FdqtpHbC6uozt2KsQ258I3CahODoSEFXLUZl/pCfhROV2ghAdZPYseUm17iLxeejETbrDjBDnzaebDE/5BiI8nE334feR6PaWUudahSqmlzPpIFSzezxc1OMWVxielOOmu7HkbUx3Z56zWE2AJSJs5/umkCnIMBxpNh0bonxZ2GP93pRMwDfep@vNmVUaMwRqXJIl3Sjk5TbrF24GK@M6/WLD6T39AuB5MGoIQ5m2YU9LxxhXnNL1B5bWor@Qkk5QLCoKyTUaVq6MeabsX77FdTbn1tmcqrOZqjMeAekqrUyZZqpK3QvonkVd0AnaoznSGUlYO9PPIrFN//X6/hC7FV9Ww9Vy6KnVq9UyCeTVYLVcc0gor7ZWy7v8EK2Wj/jh82r5J3pIxtbq19WyGRbIMKRXfniB71qE4725Wt5x3G@Zkf85iEy9@dVy3KeU50d5ZYoQKdBu0hpxxNbr62aOhgFNbKxUegocE3lYPvE@jMf/ivR/CSvHAaeQiD3OB5xZralSatKwZgyph6YNE9Bkxkgu69m8drDHhldxFlSzRms8uwyDJzV8eTUtjAQxpPKJBv0SgpCb5dkYKWsmuyM6unbiUO7kdP0SOJT1gZbD6SeU@TSphGMJ6vKmv9IgpAPvhicKz8NzCh1THWOEM1l3Blog6i@rCxqFvk7jonvf7iHe605nImxzJov0EoO1ZDrpcHw4x6FX@4M0k3Aq7gOEdhnelJNBCe6dKMZSQY/MOcn8WbcMgsEe/O6i5ljlgFpKBCHxpHgqoyyeF1gWIymRdZamKoOPULBkDo3woPmZ4zTu6kfOJ@LG47li3jRkykqVLLnSYpIK5@EU7tIfSe3x4rUGV3Hft3w1JW@w1@IAgFUyrkXka/879Pe@6O9GoTZEmKhglmI9eyqdVq8XzrITmHeSaqc7EIme2nVnKkdxDQnJaXVgaeaLeG1KxYfJhyj5UmkMfULbN2SL1wS30G1ybSGwoCUMr9IfP6/Tx8/r8wk1rZF0rvJGacmjJg1HGh5jmjRtMa7S8FldjBTe3/Y7393Bw3QH250HeNyA4QTJZZQPL3ts5ZKMbRLb8gUitVRWIsj5uDTu5uQjiXs@uo2PbenDQeNw92D/9UeadJ88eeLqOXqc4IdRi73WeB4XyGzFHc8HM5Yt6x6CqeGwG9vx0UV/OLr3qZedkiUirEkZ8KkWw356jLtallnyfGLsUjnJa1FUw/qcDAM/JZWg6viYskNN1xERJBg5D3wNxKi3RG@PV2suhw1rNHp@F@b8mL4aDRgvNRp6FkPXmBNx9@/L9wqX0ZCjQkvMu@tMhp2mqN0D9eFV9Vgdv6qpvXc7P6mPB@/Uh@r@MZxavH23/bq@o@hfbf@opjIpEzzEB8WCkui6GzQDDle9Xiw@Ugx5pz8Yi9xxdlz5fuR31at@M8Ax1fPI7764kJd8LxhtSakaLUfH2MMMOR5sNxzB3oIDmNIyFspNi@8w4uKBorxntKbtYs3b7bfCdkh5M1j7DsIgMtfeVCekHiR5ay6Ke6IkIVYpmw5xDGJYYF1TcZ/y4@yGwPhifwUSI4cEN23llSZc/N93U/C4dvjmSMGTys7B/m79uH6wf6T2Dg7p9e3H@v5Lomf96Piwvv0OSZzxzcFufa@@U@UPgkAxr@Di5NfLaLQQhTyyM1Wan3HynR9Q98dv6V1vaPDq2ufbnJFavexB@oR@J/w9aK1uZi4jqC@4QcpHBcpZqR6@fE9zvgp@wwmnOQpm@4Psu4jj564U1XOujQbLFo23TT1cadrLlVw@j@iOFUJoBZvs0MThZ08Z4GzE0woDld2BjQr2vsXvCY9lA5oqukewAcoYrFQUh75bXfWeM8gtqq3Z6cPVrtQmRoT6BUVfGFOTzQxTTNvKACguVtR72A8qbcYfiO/pw7qudjSUDOph/EEyqEfyAapoHbYj6rHOcTk6uIR4Vhvy4dfuYI@PhdWT@MO2z6vYpxon6TfuUl/FoUPhBabDAQ5ll4eDMIv7HxSJOD@C/3U6MjACCTtLMlGOEtm2jXJmSdi0cdSgzd4knDtSiRtgJ@S3R5FyKm5eHcM4KOiFElryvOP3xAQqMd1h3lNP4curoi@Lh3FIRr6qMugzAyIcbBqPuNyu1gqDu5ajkttTNfraRpLDIhsTtNsQ2J5C4I@AIUC51EqnyTMVX7AFmH5bs7IT9YkjsW/7Nzs/sXPrshmkCmirLefX8PffXU1kL7VOMnaKjB110e/BkNRKPsps94c0xlmschA7SMHmRX8wCqUPnXQL@MSJpznKjYmNavulspWqDXSYrLHX71mVnhEXz6n1jJjyLrUyx8vZeSy@kujmxPk0CYvdHdDxz/pXgXV25uEQ6TrA9gspwnxWjs3P8YgxEf0zk8iOvykERX5a2drd/pT72y8eIiOLWJDA5MboEP@IMVEXDQ8@52ODxSH0Lj3STETL6PIMpbUNnpaWGOUGGK0DL0Ja171obMZpYm48/R3XeCa/88evXytSKgfJpKPZRxdOIt08dWKq9LjMqdImIJbsJGRJ1jvmi8cwY3n9Ald30AvwINWDHMG6fSJepBYhpnVnl22SLDpst@7uGL6rttiiwiiS4kXC7o/Cz852ZW3LLSQGJcoip2NEtGcgl1zXMkvh@WoK3O5icCS/7w7u6ULsZHr4Lmi7C6F9F265tfmwZFqyYN0d7N8WgJXJ7Q@BpbZ78wHLJDkNLeb0mDm9leXYmnZxjb9M9R2PPQKDuRc7KDFQq7bLHh9RG7f1jhRwbTCJQnR0vFs7PFRZWZ9QWZJ7WDK0tBgE7HvqbWJtG/ZY2OVjpSleLMfKk/mSsmgz/y0azDOJN0dUaB3E0/SIhUV8D4cWdDci9fTMwioEW9@zQDSUS2P3xcig6EQD/kZrQEI26TSrgZmZzVyWySeMbCNwTTdPdGPbhp8trGXuRjDs4dgGZNsE@ee4WTK7/z6Iflw29YiCBe9NaHCLNGmab2idcEQVDyhjPp/uwQXdYroURvaiYC8b2sHwq5jWsP88QzEjiRIuurAl1rVyrFET/XjFqDlskIhpwIelp04Ui2ZKMCKevzy3O9RNJj0nPQWRkonwyC9srqDip9/0FMbUiOfJSqyQ22NthbE5MVieYndWw96cn@k@bKE3JsXDZFUkbRdWlfvHVCWzRKomQ/OZjTGJBHnj8eOHt8GebIUpnvuzsGUOmZSfo@6A1vcJyGgc8fY@cW593zPpCQMsIJ2Y1psBM1GQVJ0Zc0qq7TwZ2fgRLrIvRMgg9AMiTk/W6qqbCdxmQ5cZyYbOWabaYA3huKEyaqao/21xdRDIt9Z37/vrk8GGTDAd/Aar/Df9YRQkt/Is1zLWJ9zBT38LhsMeZ5P7TF1Acfga08LLdnzbTgxepVVI5PM2uyVtfTtJzG49s9fAlfD2Yh5B5rG7tzm5vZcrbdpN3au/rqkH7De1ndqLzA6zriV77oW9RQiwDOZ9CUwffIfvflSmf4SDZ0ASmfg2n8O0cW/FjSlCWvMJx/PSZqFatpYme78dNf0enJF42fuRyno/UEHeha0d7LmzdtaLm6nyhFw06DlUysvm8lkuSt@woQtIaRDSm/huTVi4qWEsJXG95rwP@ygcbAU3snvGlpN@ofS0uPEsw63reSOve/Ls1HvQrGQVTb5@rxtdDq9bn8/7F1dt1VGDX89umuPff1Pq8SP4TVfrP4hf7NJGpcCehZ8ouFR/VmTO1Qj@yD6@EfQ8L9GglVpVyTp8855y@YEXzWXckJjgUvWga7gQV@xGle7JxmmlVyludk96p5u45Ddaq4zWSmsOPvxAsyjJGDmZPxmdYk61d12D3pWCi1iONayvhii@GkJf3vjDsP@6uv8ytRsHBQBbYNrWmzfUJcD8EqzZcPck3wuuHb1N5ilwbAYKUmaJbwWVcN2d95OxHdMKCTPqFY@02eiG/47dzFIxfzkY9TnF@JUEa6mv4dfMkrnGVOQdBcpyEhrvk7hfQHCSPA4OhuTrWKyocyVR10q4O@laIE5QksVh9lM2izuFQFTf5To5zUT5wG9eAIkOqdVfuRjuJuONWC3K8y4eTDn8IV@YKJ7iEQcg9DPg0wZUwZp7xNc@MtR8vJfwIF94j2rE92TYQD7DmiJSYP6tvvD9Ji7/nAgghF8SnSuvtzi15kWKpNwd5M0FeGFLL/xxzIBrldIpS2gsYEt9lQQ4W4ozjVCtJhN9X7oGOYVW9J9uQa7Eb1PNiPO7kp1JwufU@i0CLblLOWkLP52kmGMVy5liJrNFiqVbqYGdLloevQloWI3VTtDpENJCi6WEHHjk@726/rW4/ugEdZ7GyEt6bio9l0rPS7ogleTK0wSfZCrbmbLLX5J831Q2yeZN1VVRrLzkqaebeVJJkrybi/JG@VG/ESaZt@KuFK6ME56nEnJWys8zel9S7qXKxAwep59Iuubvdd3zMZapvC/S9eM3ozsoYONZbWsywaX5Xtj5USatOAVsliVqKiXFORCqMoOqou9ganFCGhz2@XnYblUSKGslI3F4zGS3nr/I5rWS8aMziYbcYpwaWDPGiEUlrnONCXfDFxapHk6@Z4FgmGA0ZUbulik81oXHFljkumeqlVuQUwOcmjY5xCu4F/kVf8xgTyNn8i3PTlwSzG@k8XK7OU0gFrr3srPJlJYmuC4iH3WjFswiSd3jSYizhcS@tQsc1xnIHew2tsHvxXLCFhRGUkzRPU7RlE4ylAz7zutCJH7L/L3wIPPSJx170AluVBXLDJ9vYWVSF9xHQTSK4H@KXeNEl4NBB6eOrPBd8xVqHeph/TGOWxKI1syez9Rh2SP5PTzpC@lUKK8OAPkaBiJJQnR5fo7LZLgB27@GaMWOSzjKZ6q9sWxo0Jh5uC7XzAMF5xssgDvhuY2E9JyMHlA6GvjNIJ8hHS0i7ScjTW2HOn4w76fj3gjcnNGUVs5k/uUybH7eeYnz3Cel4sOSRbIrfRxczD98lFywIiKZhHU4LnxcepTJWGfDTTkbzgGgp15jon9PvBlcBb1ekKnSjMEZI1Jao2B4FbTymcxhEB8CAy5YGSeTuIfdvxw2ZXOHlC6fmBG3hCNPjsOIw/CL@VmOi5t8VuZlcGiVnDZTV1@FLRDQ3Dhp93E6zAcWcBMg9EChbjAiojxwVRolPnvWuLDu0sVGFFEDfk6ss4mYDL3@KGxSz/BOVqZDoOQYJKms15rAhOprdnxcDs7PQgDXYxIKGATMUdIiHDL60Py7cFC6YeaM3Tc9UyDp1@exQsM9GIYkfRMCc69wMQt36uDjV/UjdXSwd/yhelhT9Pz28OB9fbe2q7Y/8hk3DsrZRbB6dfCapEt8mi6n5gf0IVs9opJZTshU9z@q2l/fHtaOjtTBoaq/efu6TtAI/GF1/7heO/JUfX/n9btdPn0nCGr/4Fi9rr@pH1O24wOPazXFMkk5dbCn3tQOd17Ra3W7/rp@/JFr3Ksf76MynOpX1dvq4XF9593r6qF6@@7w7cFRTaFhmd360c7rav1NbTdP9VOdqva@tn@sjl5VX7@eaOjBh/3aoWIjAauV2zXCsrpNS1jUxO3crR/Wdo7RoORph4hHCL721NHb2k4dD7W/1qg51cOPngZ6VPuXd5SJEtVu9U31JTUu49xCFeqXnXeHNbhNAiWO3m0fHdeP3x3X1MuDg12m9VHt8H19p3a0qTKvD46YYO@Oap5CjFKummAQtSidnrffHdWZbvX9Y5oz3r2FvYNLnfyBCENYVqnoLhMYZhBoLRHp4PAjoIIO3AGe@vCqRt8PQVOmVhVUgEXFzrGdjSokIh7bzVT7tZev6y9r@zs1JB8AzIf6Uc2lDqsfIUMdBhkfiXWo0nfcavQT4SWPxKwZw7ked6eq76nq7vs6MNe5iQOO6ppbmGw7rzTN83ARbG2ihH3sGfhde2OlPf3pKoAXzOkdmdl7NLHHpJ2D3RrNyNrJVTZJeEezztMJV0p2Gs00cSK9plzWtIKzy/NG2Gv3ccc0LiYbH93o3EMQLBcBgT5lFsSg0/srXGB5udF4X23QQveo0XC9u5RMoXFbCb0NviiXq9uIaBJYeWPjp1wWuj9PEWrrB33QyYZ6OIBATqH@D2L65ncDVxUKrUAXw@V9ADZbR5Ecm1zgKIVEI192RCSjpEremeD3ULMDF3QM@HyzgX1SWEZypn5Ef3pfkxeZHKwPJJ1lu6tQwCKW0Qh/D0w1Ugm7ROA/2iNB2OYq81EQfD53inZ1WPPnz/v9luO6pgznHdE68Nxxbyl@FpxPFM9Nlmdk@dhZx0yIzLqbVZj4/FmTTOl@yQ@5ZQ7@NEb84xpsxOcDdk25Kt6s1puWzg9SHBZJntKuLXC9gjsZOt@b6l/rH7CaK64/2pz4/ir@LmML9oLwmEsT3gmXO@WfV6eSgQYY@@IgkoTaQ0ahYJUx9iZx5mvKeIFM12ELlj80V18EPK8TSUiRvfQ7dp2YjYfhjY09yeGXh9U32@/29kh0AttHTx8/2djMxG63/urJ70fUwy5t2evYgOZx0tM4yRolO6T48EixHIwn7M8MXCggI1zLm07jj/DzENttpC2ZIMjQ3AhhvXow0csGoENWsQOOexnDrzNHpmYAJ9VUF63p@jes4vukKzEPaGOWzph77QZ/ADse/maIxw3SDKRZjJ38EufS6oLlXnbPmIry4oYd9yBLPmv4WNy4xTTgrS62n8XtWn7TvG31YiSmjBiv3O1ckpC4N4mFMnYVPRnZb9nPiN4AZu9h9OWvmt/o8aN2cMfu7vxoVB0dERn34pLYp042o3WjTzTkU4T6gFM1U9NzhV1@VyPFY09vJ8eOQazRwKggzA1sfNOAN2M/IpNVsgXsi1VXfRFOhfMOwNnUHKvfiXNnNUdD2TT@Q/S78UqhBFbs5ESodh3XkTFZPsZ@LAw5U2T6U/Rg@P9EmsyA/5xWnAQ9oZblBPBOlGSoQitavjJRwmtz0GCdbiTUtD99TMB8szvmIm6YPr25kfs1RALdO2Pz4SO7PWw7MwgAJsfGhj1@Y5O0C5@WTi@yri6Oc5JesztwlJ4rzFQxBTe3ceqx2uWZsxW8uMqVvSarwtdUVL2QhdsZj3paMk0s5dX9KCvgXOP/o/CAN0DiAc9ceiFWq5OcVdSjzMgB7WrJmnBascckUku/zT21e6AsF5kp2a9PvgyhCPQW8JluJ8c86Ssxz017XOSZWB2zFzw4LscyGZOPdll3xoaYnQBw7rd4MwRhUUbXmCA6Ap1d9SXQlHOfDUVQSWJ1mPgZhLh180RanlavY@x5ZxIcGmP/ride8wPZ1TI58uLgQ2NoX5fPqzf@mFDu3K3ZwmKFB0d9D7aLqEy2JXR5hIBp9vtDUh19tJtw9MKxm1cf9KZD0Isuh9p/Ic1n4VDvSBiln6qB2iSrd55mxFk9oxaFI9xWaOWZP7hJ3QAWouKe5Ca3oRxiXsOjW2bTMbxZKynneZLynGjCbkmZiM/Vhvr6VXIJQbXL0IApGEbx4oJtNrkenDvEw@@6P/yMuR8qUK8VtGLPpBZI3guUTqr32MdjcyRNH/Qj3tGgrsAOSEyJkmykxYaqNEc/0eyk7ZqyiXdM@C7llnx/PTGTGmspqihhXF07Md9GjjoTVFrXrkFjZ6Gl9ceMyqwF17e5izH2Fpo@tlbZT71YpJRFiajcN6ojnkRuxk8f8aQ3@Sv3I4we@oIzbq2CAmHorDhXnZZzjB9sCj6EwbBl74mSJtPyB9h@46VPv8e8aLYOtdu/pj@KgjGtAJqF8KbAMBrOX/oXvcZOv@Ofh/3Qp3UaPM3fiMTD45gf0WHnw/51xNGNJMKmlak1Tp7Fv4y4YcN7fC65abnmikbBwLHNFEbDcfVC3ETwzjmMAJNYu8zfg0kfaXGZR4@TQpn0/VO2xyu5m3PLPizNKiwn@gCgBdzWhAWF3CEd8cUk6/Lp5lSGs0UZLBzPVE757hyLvRTGz4hEfAyTwtggM2WWYDcCK7O5GJ@0brwW@yAcwtFSsBsgEk/k8GfPR7xzkiI/wlKgrEpPi1ZROUW5gR9CPIznk3v9yT8Ze0LgT6BfejiLW2YxAou4tvG2FMl6RXsZJVzYPDBkGc2SmKRYeB72rOuHHOfiZhJqOnk8jxps@UNKkXazN8WVGJEOLXwQhM9pkMhpjF1MKqtq1WW/HVBBqiOnOJ9hg9vsZ3nw4xBXds4gmHY0ZMdCeh6pmkQlhH2eMK@1URafyrePmPX1u/baBAErs0zOrMjmTtZoLnwDJZT5Fcda/SEJ4@wE9bSpx2o06g9W70i9ubJjpme2WbRuuu6thsDCbBWaLB@0mLSVMR7Hm5lJfCaYJk0xtjQjHsLylZ9jNp8k4k2lgfFWaYxvocM8miV2U/GkEvd3S8Y@JsUrWPSaiSYeUow7nJRuxt9PGtTwxnwJomHK8qrBEqMBkdEYy6MFaoJMMZXuTiHmPo37BD1aRDnU2yLa2f0zl6iTRnLG5alJSjm5BD3huB2XNkkuDdowvoCbONFwYyEVK5w33piP8kq5MzgZRoIAhFYc5JJ9KNnBTTprgo84OkDbacBaqARJRE9btoVD7PQ/Jhh75debO9rioTHOlU43BdJNDIlWFZxrESRz35xeTxo3DGWKFDTEZ5AibtGUbLq4e6v@bFsoH0GQ0pysLX2LHhrjqjXChv7YSY0b6MBJVbpkakSlB0KDRQONBVqlnHcCWa5C@wuHwvGwbtDDiBYQ8tnBz5ouAXfeG8WY2ihy0xoji6vJLaPNVbktKZIwlLyD/HooiqrLC1cCEAjGVL5SIghwa8rY41CAXe/YnJdCVPcRFayUMCzpI3tFTew8Z6SDqDrDo8dWjuKsHM9sGLmZQEixmJ0nQYR0ltlZEig00c3ExcrxZHZ7khykEBveF4pTV@heSdMw7jkhIIfNLrqJRDkpKa@oOZgTHz12U4kxf3Pqs6KVWpxMJfrEGJ7kSpOpT4up1FS16@vpoqmSRA/XrjWVSKRwbYRjqfDn/uOrKbbL89gm1FpkpLQMbZ@NsOa0yqR1W/7XSD3nS9lGxzDw7JvhZvnVkBArKafsix2wq1U@MoDv9j/dWmOZajDRsQLYL5257OLIgpA11iymejQLK13jaS92UGDWtP22en@8t5dy@3o2NoZG3WD4uFgsgonPbOf3xrYaW0lhv5DOXWhfdjqFwfVfhu/PCiz7g4BDApTNCjqgLqFBEeX7w3OJDAEcKCty5/RFVqz1L9ttOwQDTijRedRtklN7Q1A8AYWx0cv7Y94AYpB6gv0FDUT7flHx6Lv2RdHUUMwxFJWGSfBV1pyeEXnwoQ377PikioFBMBtrJpq33MrWF8wgiGzCncXui90viXly9lXQ6fQ99QHxkeEpYOnbZIG9PbtAUbLghJFv915G7I/WU8FV2LHuFSOLzesAZyYmE2fC@IWHb/zD4Lx2M3CyJz9naVqhJq@hmWvwT@2p7HnW1c7i7wBW@JDQvlPurj9wmkynycw01esRnDwRRg9L3sy1TyqLy3timma35wZRZ6ObZ2cN1HSXdQHjy567l1syJ3tM3Oynm1IbNCwKDI0TfK7crQSumv3zxOLVqN2@m1TkMADSsd8lESUSyp8TiHwGwCNQDz@iJ7xo/5SjYb034VBEFBwE65iWOyjQQIFM5n6z8tu1U61W1cpgbU1Vq9v0kMup6nZV7eLD9rbapfdtvP9QWX/8eFNk7q77hT5um4/f1DbB4B3OtebFcJdeKa2Ce2Ow1kYXrxQqK97mSqPyfGszKpxUt3Gtn57@/b/@93//b/@jUNUv/wsv2/xy8nOcKZ/PF1aaX1Z@@LaJ95Pd09WVs5OVwenq@Sa47O/sNbxfH@X8xHw0PzzLLMssYH1lO1KzzmbvM7qoMrH8uv7wM0mXslpuRoVl/TWSyFEsY5ebgfU9wD3KM1rCm6ADk0v5DIK6df0xtuOpd5oBDPBoviFKEi6wA5XycrZiNu7hDibOEJ@qLGtPPKyzXgW405J4UsBdXJqxcmEvCnrYAb9inVeal8n49BuOGpp/Cz@/ic63@zfqwSdHPSiqB556kM3yT2njGX11VwohbudKNloOZLMepSRHCzAzVFHIih6vHzjWzgS5M5kVDtkDSMZNBWeWW3BevPrjyzIScC06zywh2qeSLRI@ZEKR5S8rvW/ULV8ox7ds6qoNKwoNvYrhyqwTlbh/oQL5kRgCJDV3hSDlPlWJkz6@kYyngvmi@zrD0YQYMMh6@HKPxz0@0Fy00tM2z6m1FMIcsfm8fMXcuCmXoRltpEj9CQJ8oCLLySLfJFxdXs2IlbfVSm6m3MK226eZT2wdxsHI2KZLob8piwnEmtsm3EpP32vRhtxyvKKyYXy8YlWVnbT9VhmrSPeyMwoH@roC144B9SWu7ZuMJPQoAxI44rO/PD3CeKPAeIqa6BYJljVWrT6aLiOhp6@mUwe7eTk5sohQ@Nmhsf11Ymy7Bb4lYthBeICRik352n7YibTXlSET@9wfniE6oN/mgGojOTfj/TxEbZ3AuN@Okc4zZDY5T8YzNWV5MPTPu76nlvf7x0N/XKdpizSfUTPvUgvhgglIYPDpqmc1zyAsLdJdwhSJm8KWQwhe0Bnr8GjSt9n4zgm61AwF7XYFgyDFTkzJ4GuqrybomHD1d3SCjfKU8I5PI7WIZckLSyMNKWtfm@FhNjV0MqYGe@zEAyebEVTjkWl4QRe6xETb5YNfkuQd@AjQdWf1LUB9FWHjGerH7HQe9PzU5DToZMxF/8KmknkR45lDUYo1UkZDeVJKIt4BK9Ijf057gZC5ybgzyiw5ztKnSIdzW7bnEXbyHdviF3wVxgHoOIAZ3wxR73qhCMuJGSqJgZFXdbb8Jwjtjn9O@I2v/TFY8dOy8@O9gnvy86fe6QPnU@/rp99dxkSLZDPL5tSyPsw2EkuPFZoZC17q1VilRcbV4KdeOsOnnpI7LBYJCJGCc/Jz4fRrgRD6tOy6DwqfloUgqS4DJoXF9RUAvjCF5nIai8JyZsl94JrOd34suYrmVv5FH8oHV34JC7Oo5G16WucM2wSK7@n@dilXTqLC0/Xio/XSI1oJnQc3uWFwifk2F12eBTekSkRYztLU8@n3FDekCPHtJvI36eMNtVPCmsjdk0hfUtIiVA9zricTsxWVyQtPUH6iMrtLxRUXN87j4/ARC35PEcuZvOwLSkwHLe5zMH9G/S7q8SPItcnbIcKRsDIQGxHeQs0Bsgm@Mo9DXTNcVvmeU17twHcrA6HuLSxbs0Wv38tpZc3Nr25Cicatmc7T4tPi5BidGqKpEbqilanVe6q09eOTf/ufB78tj5a31gsfhvQ7Wv5teePpsjzSA709NG9Xy1vLz5Ft49vyuEBrYHp88m//m8pv/YXgIGX8nP5sPTawNsbLW7kKF/m6vLVBD6X1dar3//zrv1IbVmTFhlisKw1PMWKbhiI7fo95l9JVHa2UZelqIlb4YhZgiIUhrc3pBYZRN@tPi7xNt6ytKq4C7fnK2KPoKZ4Ns0ZsKiQ7GcaegjQjKVBBBTkBaUwo2sqy3TBmG2DeBE31y/38RkQrgF@0OUdcZWy6cT@CydCKLIuoAx2pkdbz8rBV/DEbm3eUs8amZNOokFjaaVn79OEmscPbfjAKm2krCTNcu03/OjjLgw/zQeuS1lS9qNP/dVi4IpbsltafFtrY3C@wHXdhwJByg3H@d1IEdTAgWhiy0amnhtQD/S5ceHkcLYgU@r34TMrEkyQtexA0ZQ8rHZOYssgdP0@Oh9GcfKJKO/yXFHhEztSBIK1YaZ96VPLgsKyya3FGycdrXhfYvGXjWO0CIyfWsAOWTfkMtwG7g6Y9@erwnC8hcSl4XZcseb/Vavg6zcksZU2oNC@zdBF0BpVsW9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNnAslF2IHIZdjQQdY3WDk0xK9kuUvWI8nNcBNij5rjV3FJWRt67x6Vd@qcNSVBVVfS9XX1KPQEpJ6Yp6xvLEpO5vIlgq2KodBA0dqMyum2iITtHmY5x9gEEm31Nu4lqCbwzcgiWpJc7RVmd1tHq@FiUeuA7mzJ1uLErk6s5xcfvRMDrlBDd0J9ealMhIQ8IJbhoUyvR/JDYiKCTMa9jLiz28i2fj30GC4DQdwJWq7rRPnozIt9a4Q@yYc8V1KRSTQfmVtG@yMzB4x6NjFVhyCNouNl6wLlmqXebHFGU13lDkMtHEJlc3KPtVJU8XhZds6eq0EiqAP2WJp/eGjxxtPnj5DlLMl3drZYFAoj1XA4MInGKxRO7TIxvdKJbualU8IQT1dJaDPAosDOJh1Xbuucft87d6rlIoaWDHLsK45jIYU19uVDDKBOAzymBFojeIMs47zY/kEDTv91HK/0j/ib@MfkBnOuKP1hfRWP7xNPFNluuJwoMKCmZ3iOA/hQcXVKXbeoN8@hLeJALauwvZU0Wt4gBhdDPuX5xc2d@S1a6tjGjBEcPZLjRXUy2CUOBizsIIuqjcc6tbti4qBdzLdAhjlYkqAzifAaZhpv5W@tjTF6FilSQieNXFjFUeIlumozc7Mnb2@qu3vTiK2bIehY7h527KVlDv2ZAYHMojVazX3mKirvV3wVVItk7yUV2UWcEXkK/F1eB93pZsIRG1Rxchq1htGziKylJgXE9emSVHqR@A1A2apeDspzb1W0woQxAhCvZsUCzEvPs@xSZbgZHcyxil4OVu2bETfhFHEDuZ0ZVlXW5RyJo4qsJSZAxD7NsWsNKRYRo/yY40DL0tvI5ij3IrG1oA2Q45XqsHMnBxmgq1uI3GAjajjhhZof31/x1O7Nfqz92HXg6K8Xf0J7Y5DPM/Ht6TxLZVVfc90ge0tlm1uYTP1G64oEbMUtcPYBEEI37ZERQwSrwG1@p6mvQzqk9TYPk24AuzqayXc7I7qQQJHL7wHsqQX77ErDr6uw9/Ksnk1LWlilyp6WMgW1@KBbdFkKak1hiSkvAOI9UkQsaOWhNuXEoYXC3TWvH29djGMXd@bzdMplpUFFantewUie5pn51JmEVusa7ZYL6MfF/EF8@1C3jgL2n19Fy1mjlt4494f443c3Zkj9/8Fc9T@OdzxUHPHwzJkj3BH7Dacb3RyGPb@DI45G/Mc3GiF5yH2h9rWKxpR9CwALPCAIe6QUmKpiLbNESfKmZ2wNjkfwUho/TEuBvyhxj/SjX9Uhszlx93g/9XG5/7BjX@sG/@4jLlmRs9r1c5yt/6PaXGiEjrpDzO7F@quZHP/aEs3dEs3yphNZ3Tzf3pLc/9BLX2iW/qkDI8JcuAg7usXc7NoItWjnXo9MbfIZ7TTLgdx7GdzpYu1V6uSpcVDu3MZXVSgras/jP9Tjf9TSCN@Qhg6nEXEtqHxWl6Wp3JZXjRL3uVQuGQlLZH2Gs/oVnv1hJWsR/QEJUKaN7aGeqFCCrkniclpUz7RHxPpG08@d8VZZLsOlomDc2sBLSvCkpsMcdF8dZDM9Y14XtllH8hq5/jw9dp/ETJ0/c/6Fhohj669DjodM5PYS7Dj2OuUbozVHMA@0muOFKtocjKyI33bO2aXpflSjR1bTMyLsxcJctSG8z9aS3Whb1hRubFlRLTJ6/JmVQXTXLO8kC/Udsk0u8m6xX@IS59pLn1WVod6YTCPVL7e8NO8mKzT1h8/XjQHSKk8fjAAix7lXzCq/i8)

[Get source](http://savannah.nongnu.org/cvs/?group=qemacs) (this is newer than qemacs-0.3.3.tar.gz):

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.nongnu.org:/sources/qemacs co qemacs
```

QEmacs has utility html2png, I use it to test this answer.

The code:

```html
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
```

QEmacs ignores top-level text outside of block-level elements, so in `aaa<p>xxx</p>bbb` only `xxx` is rendered.
If there are any rogue `<` characters html2png segfaults. Most of the polyglot before HTML code is already commented out,
and the part that is not commented out doesn't contain rogue `<` characters, so nothing needs to be done here.

I use `<!-->` to comment out the text after QEmacs code.
`<!-->` opens a comment in QEmacs, unlike HTML standard, which treats it like `<!-- -->`.  `#` is for Flaks, `//` is for Maze v2.
Note how there are no `<` characters after the `-->` on the last line.

Sciter, IE 3.01 and Attache also consider `<!-->` to be a comment opener.
Sciter (JS/TIS) and Attache are fixed by moving `<script>` and `<attache>` before comment (QEmacs doesn't support JavaScript).
IE 3.01 is fixed by `->`, which closes HTML comment in IE 3.01.
Another way to fix it would be to use `<!--->`, but that breaks Navigator and Safari.

`,h1` in `<style>` is for HTMLayout.

Comment: it can finally replace the 404 page polyglot

Answer (score 3):

## 143. [Beatnik](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 6220 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rL1rb@vKdiD4eRPzD/Kltux7JFkPknrLtry3npZsWZL1tPw4PhRFSpQokiap5z6@yGAG6STdmOlJp4N00p17b6YHE2D6Q9CDAbrRAQaY/tq/4nwNBnP/wZ1VRVIPW/beJ4lskcWqVatWrVq1alXVYqnHGcPf/e4Af1BNlZcDWTWRKRgm6uvSTNCDKLNEnznJiIbCFIWh0vpgOhEU0zimDhCLkKTwUh@ekamOBUVaCTrEhxDSdHWgcxNkDjkTCQbPaYKB1KmpTU2kivuzhRHKT9SRFMA5J5IyADBT0DVdMEl6BKGWInOTXp97kRJ9UaCmQ7qBcoL84@RHE/HqZMIpfQMgYwjlqpl8Of0CQxyhK1U3BIyHFwxDxZEJhBZ5gX8BmgRQTpfUcrpy/iKJZdA5kM5psrBAXM8wdY43JVXBSSxqVFqN2k4OwtKarvanPK6uORQgGbNIlGTBoHioyhnS7IYJ4gA6QLrA9S0wSlR1hLOgyVhGEuI1DfVkbhjkkSwBbIFJIAFzFK0gXR4aaKFNAIOhToRtOgykCEIfGZrAS6LEk9KRsDAFxQDijSCS@DGaS7KM@oIMGTYk8X5AhqbGVpRFQJDqqxSCD6@9qMD66VAAGEVwmCBowFTMBBW3AXDE4cVc5zQNiAQmNoBwU5qAKEmm20ACZ0hYWCGLISh9wj9tLcYq4pTtWqKZxCEO6J3qBLch6LhtggQvGgq6ACi5tSB55rpkAgswe9OoJnA6auqC4N0V6Z0ioTAVl2DiigRJ852euvPVghua0coR5DSTOtDDzesLikPBFDp8PIFvyuU6ofKVHPpyeI/DlgRDU2u6h/Oi1C@RQd/fC/BdsD16oD9TgJUCrsiIVjWT5gIaEBgwgUCaw0EcCsxCQU3eKhidvmiLLeGyoPrQGqikoLaf1Iyf6jrupRumcmOotKwqA@AnVFafKpgfCoox0AS8Cp3Mj4QZcE1VrDZS54TDzaEEjWbgJtnqF5auIQwFbQOyZ3PUKddQ5SmBg5yGiQUQuAJZMcaSiNpI5CQZZ4F0jMqiWheMqWziPFOlj1sedInQDyKHDF7tY6CJOoPiOEBKIqAvTbZ6ICEKgKEhVFJVnPTTv/zL/mAAeNI8r@p9W1zbqK/yRCtyhFhQNQgLrKpwMiEL4Py4dCs7FDDjZKnPmbh4ZWkXQYggpc7VqdxHKhSozyXoWkNuBt1RFAXeFCwhtxSpH024saU3JEtyoeITrgcNSwogZZNqB9DnLLQSL1AHRGYCk6kpJlBAyyO3QX/v@XTs@fTxXgDivEHv0SFND05A4IJHJAqe3O9JTju9o@gMkzNUqU9pS3OoKiEU4JGLT6maoHjcOzjcfrfec3uDWJ95vCdSig@KktL3uEHGM1Cu23vCp/g76fjh5EXu7RIByxxjwb1V8PBeFwUah/SJGT3hJCWoLVE7YIe20lTjEXMcJwe3ojFfXsbNrIgDMo5gsVSxfIAaChqyIGgeJsh6sZbAcHurjRP2VfQFDrvCx9KDz33g9m1XnWCAmu5UFPfVpqRirSVrwynoaGCKYmigvXUsujwHwmNgJW7CYO5HPSLWRPODYiEqcS64dQH1QI86YkR6pNXjcP4A1pM2hk0PcuB2O7TQ3@rPoAugS5vGK6Usq3MomNCGhy/QIAounBtAE0Fmq0Jpq0JWiSRmt2pjBfQKxtYTUCLQk6Av4F4Hqt0W/a06Ang4ZMEANquvbKmgCbcELLw1JG76DZJE6FIT0BL6EvECVj2ggwRrXMGFTEk3NMCMwQYNEwhFo7td7VVPM3U6HbgFXb2i3@1QuPLbfQrrGyQKcyRzymDKDbAlpUAWjucFzbT1FdTEMEEjvRx2SGTAHkODxpA6/PyybDKW2KPrVhlY11utZ4@IHFYyti0VkEGnIs62BlFf0kE7ycuXpQPA7EXhrh8wyA4BP7jeIMExBEDIhIXAT01QbiDI86HED0F2MXWKpR6tsehl8RC1XToo@IC4LhoTw559F6KC9DoKk/EmigBu0dd4YIzFqM52Ikjjb0e8j5kzJnsQq2sSYTzYig3SXBBk7ys4J6qi7kEKjFyjxSC7KVY7gEHWwMYgjF@O9UU669pCXDcRtBloD@j5IH9D09SMYxguJHM47QVBUuimviyZVQULC23qS8lUrXBPVnugng3on7RTAs1Pe9LiRYVI3LoNRwY1AztMNFAKBvCnKUidxy0aoDhJfBYDbyW5iAInKKyrCwAJUBAY5RENopILoFQaS4X3uIKkKwWh07n8yIU7rssLAZxrzZesOsFaCHWIfYANvowOmksEbWXrfqL6ub0j3noMIOad2x0cqZLi@eL@@PGj@9h9Bhr@48dPEDrFoU845IPQJxIKkBCGC@IQyeEnIZx6R3LguAf3852DeeF9wM22wKPTStI83N3xcfjBz92x9j2E715QdaDZADqAb4DH7U2lcNDrdZ3NoaLBnmjVvm5xtk@koS4oA0pYaKpuoko1l3@spZvFlIueGjotSz1agfH1cQI9GOYyrj35YVLiZIdgXVXNFGkwHE@gCwBkz@EoU51Cn4f5hzSRzBKZ/cgKFuxNozmpWSh3g6AmCSZlj0YbWccToU3bQD0IfGl7TiTq6mSt4QxK4Icqch2GXdiW35mm4mHfTo3g1Kk9Sd2Kj@P4CZ5gBnlqwPMooFqP60gbMIEB8aQzCJM5auDzYUgyCV1H2pBJghJPRIN6z4n8wjLPOH49C90aR7Yx7kt/O9MaOUuQG8rU0HDlCM/2TKdt@BgG7qs9QV7EIgFBFoPmYhXE6iIWoawbCvTfgtiTl1qs9mWgTOj7gYX4IoHTKYvCJoxhZZiyoLJkkNWH7Wam1h3knnJZHTi8Ozq5NimhjSm53/51bWMhwgwCMlaxutyEHsHYi@6ggOn765yiZAzJZQf0FUWvU0huY9ITyWUPwLFtU0GXwBN8zJILPD3EZp2qIkWYEzAyOhBkwCpJ4eg6ueFxYh89uyPeDjE9QZzClJHuSQoOfwUskEwQSLHXk94CBb5g0p37HjB92tvHNhCu4SujCO0w3pzqpiz07ft/@/0@NMDr5hlyS5jq8ON14BH4hpsqIL7ZWnZW/EAu@1uWwIymssQRNpDQ11DyHJ6OcvI6sB81VskoEBhyOjTu0mlcEE58geH1HTmzKNcFedoXnPv@QgiLd00vK7ciTUiN4I7tSDKOvpH9heFo5cfTeV1WuT7BYi2zSMKmta12ERbcACpHb2kk0JDfQKdj36HNugoYMubUuuKllK@1q6Th736uHO8KGRPleqwA01CuJ73BR0xG7C3JtjoMNj0CosyNreAjDu6vrFUdXRoMwOSy72@BgX0NUyCN4wV6Tm7viIUzGCAy0HPv4dRl6/oWiLMovA68BQhVlcnl5wgfEQceegiWHbygGdhik/SCsTLXW2ITbfjzpQgXSEZZUDIp3udjwnjAXc@AN0unmvZ2fmwhkPzJ5P7c1iorQcCroigIX@u5MPpIE04OhPpbwTcVsWPSbkJ7QEfcjANjV@YMEBLTZrMwg2Yhl/cEFw8oPBaXTegdsd2Q4yx0vDVX3uTRJF6VJUMjze08vKURX84yNmjwOjq5bLLip9f87YNhjwfrwDq0v1OrvInnq2/I0TcoKWuqiCfjW4IRVN/iHa/O8fdNM2GozgTrun/gWu2l6htUUEAmkgGTxdfZ@/zXxBUvfJLLfi6O91Jl8vLe@GN0par6UFAMFAoy2MxRyGo9DNuybM1dm6Xq2zJtSLJqoAa5vscLmBAYhnXdL83bbJM4JcAPrT62Du/PtpcoMsihNLm@0bicPFDlWGJAc3B5UwKmuog1vX3/Vg231lAs@1UNtTZ6VIW172@q9jH8f004yDqsjpcntoLv2FL71Jk9rX27gjAvwGuO@ytXYBIkZ5C2ZnFvNYDOD@fc0rn/A0aPt7jrjB7akpjMYNPhDMkEBEzdMqP/IaVF3i@t/2066hXa@NcqsdW4Y1kAjU2ur5oUhRj2Z@ZgGebbNZYoT4WpsFeDVHsjAcTmPd3x7UQxdjUO7XUPGpiHt2jXUCt7QvhNVOPxHD@9q3A4WYJO/lVrZq@q0cDO1vAEugaBGg68zjhQptpO427xrj5V6u9zbqg5PVvt7xCJU36uRkp83WbaMcUNgXzfMtvzExWmveoEbAjlG9rfRkqWiKzrDmISs8E8kvBqlf4u3mO0XscE@xXsEWhVaWwE8JLXtyme0FvzdQKcTMKMTBHMJb6@xe19irSnqvLPaR3Qp30Jm2lgfGJfha@10ivbx17SRpuVCQOvcvTEt9YkrLHGnjwC9/BE@c2GrkGVTDI4fEsrv1oDfGfU2loR/NocEkZssvBj6LwTfoveOu7cbDARjL9LsLMqRjuB95Alg@FvsY80x@glC654kdZalt04Wxy80D/aEjgl9QMGPxQmAnl8x@Ln@qOp4dzeBFqo@LsnOUiTJdM38mkSdHgFX3eWgLdMIlNVBIM2OX0g4LmKLHBgjVqxbylZZyV2L3NLE24gFL4qWZtlB7zZyevSTnD/AsSxtf/AQ7avqBFrGqgqY2FpOPf9xvKSh/acTt7Ftq@T83h186u9OkjvXX3@is2nDNWhMhSGOukZ66e3@gZIpGm5Yb1XCaB/yBljvLtrKyTNLKPAE9qa7Q2NbT7Lqix/C5@xarQUparuX4LNY/@qPmT9WXiXXA8S7NtXV@tgBCfsIkP5W71oKExhoDJUU9WEAHl6C1TGaz3Wdf@qcqnqNlBHEvQ@rgmWygkULfVkAc0lIGFkbO8T7F9H6skqh10J3rHlgTPO/VtWpnhV32/TnXOqCWbq@2NvgdDztRE6I5l423/wFcCd5ukJnKlIY9ru6fbjXom2d8@It9V6Q97w225iECfptlOQsfa8OygpvC6Q7XlnuxYdYKeB6WQqc6aqBxGB83g4n8/rpaxMeMo@UADMgSK@T9ghwnKrMpAsGSaBlUR0d4cOvyyOmWP2GaWQ69iFHh4srGRrPr/QiNNS3cp6d8g9pA7dgYD70H2vHCPGTUAFGWZQe0G5HThRIjeLzk3VkcJNiA8GDjs1PbEcPYwh8aWClumDrLTABCDLPapuuStYPjFNvM7/X/@mb7uYgc430EQywGIeKNgtUp0IQ3X@ySrXLj2taRx2UcM45kO8kI1LD2TTyABJhzGOeJapc9QqNBO2o4rtuAkPNazpt6iwGhVbH9h9yrQazaKmrwqWPNkFr3M5leJVeTpRoH/1zaERRA3odQJxhFlvXUIIgymmjpVM349KqC/gFdY@JoyMsLKqjsmeLKbkv/6N5Z4DiRIWIRx2iifeeVslImw1EJ8YnlenQLWDZCXoqg3iwUwGLT/Fxiv0BsGK9yJ@yBG/IZDEgOM1g4uxPGey6QYK5JEbe5fivfgTSfQcpuvn7TvmIfVLNKGF//b7tPeLzTfXLwJx1nD5kQNy8ozlajuZgeRNqhu5Dhcuu1rYj5G47a2FyvZV9uAwaS7HC2ZCXCCJ3Alz4gVDNpcVPIhh30LFgP4Bj16C2uo0qUPP1LKUAg0TRbELLhgfHIQsp0niTYY9OnCWwwX6EQ2xrAR4xEYZeLIYImMnokkq4@yShbc3Mumc0JuSRf1ZKBgKp0h1Dh9Tp2ckpAt9Ffv03X1/vwgxgftFPP9AGw5z7u8Xv2BCN8A9FVT34Xc07kD5Su7LYfCM@fFHg1sil@vZfWJt7EIvP/xSK9XyjWa62WoAN5@tyh4UVH3CbTQFlgVN5njoPjJxlgS26JJgfF17rDXI@gnAPR50yKFT7GXt9a4T1qA2q10B16EVXIOANbOd@yvZ9@U3hK301wC2ZhIlZGtRVCOCZMuM29jWoH5HtnC74O4@BZ3tcARvs@9RhYRHLpQCLgWAS9/II/S6llYLfiIR0IxfZ9T7OPahAF5tIF4DYCaty8L1tdKtyu2t/PM/QY01GNf@sTUmON6tMYZ4r8YAuMlGchTSpXKrnt/NBOK08YwHO1HH7zuIpG9ZPraWdKm2P6ejmYiJZdh@W2vdaqCZZBATDMubiEcGmM@Q7kj29gysXRBWZEGUlg3Q5P0@qKbe0sSaDVR6kPhzWE4dAQW5DoBZwfVA60cuCsMaqdd@faC55jDt53@wMh8SOILZoPb4Id8L9E//8i8t3@N7E8J/ZIdFCP8LK/w9jRn02n/SonHNGsyWdqmGDGL74YpPuMVWnfCIhUdESZkKSJoAB2eEIRjcInZT3w0ez10b@AmNAMzEqhdrW1KeoD94sPfbMU1jAwPP24PEJ0BY8MQqJM5wT1PsCw4DBB2LxiIsDUQGZg7CgGQhDGgWQq/3GGSNmkla6ocej05PT5HL4DlZSMVOLEbSh9z3YdcPa0IPAZaybJE7BHkgyyYHpJ3Z2TyHnI/14qy4y7lZN3o4ATPDahcYqTwkACBeHK3Y/HDBUKjarIJGV4SFSdT50rGxwMBRiFOTYL0R4CAKACILN3ZZfim7m61m7IKzJc3B7WZwdTBYA4Mdu/aJzt336N68Vx5sz3UEAvPrPYKkQPiP97izr6Un/dqR2vPSDRrXBn1uKCp2PygAtcgTokNhmo15t3qKy0YF9OJ@8SOghJ4APYsXpJGqGelsvnRRrTVeOQITSPdLMDdyn5367gNB/93DOuB@IfUOUzMFunGVKTis3KZqs4KHITbLeC/J3FfaS0rfKL1j7fG/LpskvCqIZb4VMZkoBwpkpfs19k0qvQWYtfYgX5Xq8X55vns4PbtXDl4V/@O@dyQOgkdYuCB0b5A3JNxoj84pOZ4LTfxemxF0XOFCrs0bQGsHQOt5E/22K@/6LbmNP6/jI4F9eUNndF@Y0cpUlqngG94TUPcgbRVFnFktwhx6Qdc4pLKY1E2BPPVqFXabGmTX5fULfbZP45pJVWt6St5V4BSYmegSb0EbREFbk1jiWA/TmJK5mfnAbAqvnJEJ3pJMZkBVrHd0@xJZP@J0x9lyndIQJlKg6dCDFcfGPxcUGfY7HULdZKl3wqXuFmjtCfie627Q0GTJ9GCf2UUQTxKhNh4vrgB7KgvY5fY0@WD79yLHDddHPHlrU@BXTdXQZmKeE5xQHeZmKDcF5CAGArqYTgBOJLe6gEcJAVXUAGQGProdIu6gFI9dh@CkH4XSg0Nh0ZcGMNJ4vH5QSb9g2Y0PMOf1wYTaDXrYYtU53qreZszP8lve4hh3xwUlpS8sPPgdleMHzB2Id887M7fX9UoGiPO07Undf@lF7SgLzrR77cYD@YVCSCbXimC37ySTwaFBYU9NmFdAiQ1TL0MQxlCPOOE05JkSN3QDBRF59Nx7FL9h6l4UOMPj2RwpyOcjMxK4kYQgIjlFEpJkvCLkwS9veegUtDOONZQ@vq0kDd2xweADhEkhXnSI1xSyYG7g2biXAoMTshwTtDAAw98xpmgOcy9MkXU/JMVSeEFAB6i9yaQjD4akAwIvSK3R2Xdoow02PdDiajJ5bLfGrjpMIhCL0z0aA9DuUXOOxQn8td3tgGtYiQFUFqaaEiiUz5eCokB/9YDMTKB3Im4KQqZ7/c4Lxf7NS2mkhAOLxKLtvweE7r6slnd/kVWwZw7pEzKvPXmGcf@Hezzwi/bQv6R/jw7SJ188h3JqSYMx5j3zHA5TrC985PMdKkeeQwWbI999h6fDz4dg7TwGXUHXAoACh7L3BOQZrKPUoXJyyJ16Dvup0BHJAY8@n/cLZPilQQe/HHLP9OF3YE34IUa3eqfn0PDi7sAEg@wz0Id7yCHtB5n54nEhF3kdGBd/KPl8mIbg4SMm4Jf0fcNHxpX7Bk1m3ie2kUsPJo4a2bVV1i3x6vVmi4F29PFao0eJH7a1RfPoAG@/q7YnbZ999LvfHbAxmER9ioU96qdQ@OPRATr47KKPXLrry30Ozdx3nBgKPj3UxrXajffeAyLpPshWXWzE9T1CRzR1QB8xP8Zp@ocffgDrE92dBc@CD967gPvhzoPQWTx@5I8ljvyf3SyZRMOEjGW9nlDIS6P7BrqPc9yRLxL6rJxIkqQZ/T581SEaoxV8xiLC/yS86m@FORzuiSuw5FQ87UlhcfoAH7bmdkfD7sb3@A2LTx/hj/zDZ/2Irx9JjB1NQF5/PnqR52lBHZzxB6sDlmUPluTvEYdZdrHv87gVplk2dK98wO/Axz5@/gCsEXzkc3z8mcx3kCuecKkqeUBDwBpF6gGMkAsB9RBaBPCHOlg0OfyHmj38VzfxX3uM/@o8/suM8V95VV7tpQjo/2Uq5fu5n2Dw0QlRBz@c/pD6R3xI/YAOmLscnJ09PD/7AnfB7098Jyf4i/@h3zvBE/KxQkDEgy/gO707PQ2enS3OAg9nd9TBF@DJM3UQcoGQ3h9RB6nFaZ1Qepc7s2l@sqfjZQifBh7uamUwuZv@0GngIFRIZ/2hRitzwMJTdPOIE8P4sZ5P56otgK6V8@lG/rzUzrdqEG88PJ59/uwLQqt8Dp49ACWLX/jOfCnTNNHt41EQvft53BOyHqmD3NmiRQdOgdiyHVMnxQTu4eneC4X9SB3cHdx5PoU@hRiZmTHsmB1fqdXNf7UK8dKCGak6M2SGbJ9IaKQaq35GjNBilsxywUzUKtuHoAB/zASCEiMumAGjMArL7qB7@39SVa@qKqBSIZu5YEyMlRHhPqhWrwCZCOWP4E9iGGYBdC6YGfwzMuk07PePDKm1l7m/p@6Q6wcB1EaQdQcZdzDmdksP0Zj29OU5FHu6I0ZFNPlwJywk88GF/O7H@7tkMul@ODmgjft72tKkrlDEdYJBnp8fH3PpZvrxkcZrLIvTQ99nX@AzfFJnvlP79umgf3by6f44gOXbkvHg4wF9@un@DLMcwqf0z@4ra1Rw/3hPuT3zTqeDv535bG6FSMCKu@@sU/GlQ0OUFcIPc/jM3si/G1i8FjKP5y768OXZ6/V@uHefuC0GeTxIAAvc42LvFyERhVxeYponYVxjw9h6ikW9Z2exKDzHEt6AhyHJVpZ7l6Zp964gmeoHiQdRKpXWdW5JgCIwtN67OP3x3nUXekilklESHQ0kY0jVA8mw1@X1fs@entplhLwQ7XIvXKruRl@et/88X55PPeTjxX9eL460r2deDyR7o/C0@OJZnHpOPTgOonCuL89nOEjgvkDozuN98D4/W3Fw9XhPLZxnXuAbXs/4J/xXDWRoyH3wfIBNIgVFol5Pbyl4IzFPwpe0/1IfoQIeV9gdhnq53Jz77u7zUfgoHrn79HD0cOQ5PQoe3Z897Khtr/sAQRdxRDrFHmC@UQfBk7qLDbncWMRP8MaEKgtBWR2gcPJkVxjcj56jl58Em/Qd@T7fHSWTVtlHRz9@hN4I6KAwF3wOQH6RB52ena6Fao1x4T0D2C/IZjKEn7@AnFmJYGF57K2H@/sFQ7q5F530UodfDrjnE4IfPbvcJzvySvB73Cdkb8r1xXXI6Xfsg@vZdfil94xN0SPWSyyeaOTk5ChiheMJCLNHXmu5NcrAkxOGFMHgeKIQTg6wOLmB516oVaonDCQFzM8dJvmi0SgdguviF7F8aEGd4D0ca8PIFXBZHQglkgTfATKMJAWznR60/BzFGRirZfx2hCqKH614mLahniCA5SzIMl58xLMaMO7l/hxm0h@pA9BfYEAZAnwmNU6YCsJ8Op0L609WMo65EfKMYFaOPz/9@g9@@vX/@NNv/uSn3/zBT7/589/@6s//AL5/A98/se5/8h@SUXz97a/@l//tp7/6DUT@F/j@Z/j@p9/@6t/8vvUlz38H3/97K@7v7O8WnPWlANc//@2v/vSvf/urf/EX8P139vcvXn5/@rP/aP3/P/YfDv7mpz/7O3yxH/7gT6i//9tf4/8//du//8@/xv//@//693/7r//@n/97EvhLK/D//rv/YF2h8D//45/@zR9Cnf4Mh/8ZhOEf@QLWx2cD/BGO/PGQAWMS3f@4DfkjzcLQg@ityD9CP95j/0x2Awn4/@2PNMNCtAW5xrkN@ce//dW/@muI/RFGUZa1If/QyW7L0A7kDp1Q0B8B5F9tAfzRT7/@/Z/@@n/46dd/@dOv/zkFJjH8f0QfqRDCd3zBkSRAQosjKhoGOXXC7CYcjpBwFK77LA68U/Pp806UhftoHzAB/ETSP@41YHAZRw5t@wr76OTfi@ET@gzJMGaRYWuBr/gBYnCYqDxyc6IWNiB5tmDs562cVoz1jLay78bjyK2Mzm1ftJVAinSAkI1sYReKNujtalAOZRbw4lUEhezqUVQctWpwqZfOi82tezOfzhapGMpUK7kXt6gNFEXlfKG5foxbqU7W6BpFN18uv3y0b111ingOKydy@sKCnI8UPD1lWeqskW9CRLOK2BATpM5u0CKIarVrCuvDjyga9/uDwSBc8N1PPuQePPzeAWHftoAPDJdLLa@oK7yRkGQtvw4J54OQLiTxTjYo07lCHAl6@BiOqfZ2JNxwFA7q0mBoInOurgEMwwATam1dOZbV2sLqoB7H4e/P/UAJwvbHfD/CtMogca9S5NfgVBHGlAl@Hx57WZl4Yi2JiKGCeAQKhZKJaCIZDiX8iWQiEmVj0aifDfnZeCKeZPwwpU6wsUQ0yfoTkWQ4Eokk/dCQ0WScOhCUviTSNEyUWJcLkYCk8PhFz1P8xqwaHJ5RB31BlBThA1p4@t4PB30nAk0TyBVO3DPIRdMuNkbhDcijRQpsbrw1G2ZBe7koF4d4dFAoZJlCweXK4AdQwEyWcbn6@CGaYJh4xuUSSEo2EWZCkGmIn/IxBrvNuyT8kE0XChjDCD@EEhiHyzW2UqwH2XmIA5iCH8JhjAC5XE9rdAwgVy2KEiSXaT0wTCbrck0t8hLwB3Bp6ylCiM3jB5yAMxWslCykuVznTiYYV1yuugVnF1V06ptOu1wl6yGdxiguSOWjVqUu8UOafCCTDk8gvi7XAAIDHSwGl6sHQSzELhcPIX7JQdwEQtjNVDE5l2tp1QPXxOVaEGiOH7tcj048lAP0FIvc0OwLA@uz1K07D0klSJIW03yhd37eGwx6@jKdP6@TpIuLIjdaTvXeoGdn7D3CR8W5IGk8Wb78CDjp8ZGT9yddQpLyIulx@SgQCh@5J6DM/gxwQZPHC5x0AUn7FjFshPCZAHAPfzITuGe4npXkfEgSuS96PdcJSC2F@w9aerxfyITSgwxpJYDa8TD@KUx3op@mCVcs7jo@grvrkysMwYUHMW4wYF3ue5fLe5d8@OSKR13H7k@fAu7v2E/IFU@6jl3xuAt5T1wh6HxRlyuGQnGX6xZsPmEQcKNPrhNdMKe6gkInz5iCVYo5IZSgJw@@c3587Xm/2GC9k2e8tA1kPnlWvhTrRyvvJ0wxzNtghus9JnU4eabpU6waWLz6QVNnOE/KWgwHuIRrnWIpj3XvRzC3DQYRfAMBCqdrKYsPHlfSg8AoFSW43ruIzW6tUHrc7njI7fa6TwDJR@Ta0ufeE0IrsnjqcRjjAlYAY5IwxbRr70kGYAKEAkmg/BVJ@vjYMDkdL1mTEo@RK5Z04Wh87l/SKeyzP8D6j4960dOz/46yDPIYSx08U3388mckiU6SJ3hVCGaKp2d2nku0jA98xS2ST6hDNybaHd6ZNx@Q6yE24g4CYTWiHhweHlIHp80zV9hVDT6uVwPOaLKWdH92Ekll8UQfbLzg/ePpx5@/tIYzB88@OwtiZ3gp8NUnEqF0ATtX9fHRgdZEPhHFfB0g4wDQnPj@IR8omUoBUuoEz/VcBxp0Ll5GS7wUie6tip7@8oDM9FHti@PsMlXIftzxFd598XDHDfKa/t0D8v6yIslfEuHAGVm@xhKKoKWfG8nv498nvr9qVVvVwmfmOHGcuL@3m9PPulk3aSprKewzjFRSPU8dGD961Sj7S@Xi5OBYc4cjbjB871MHVuXZuPfgLBQPGtzy4MH2FPVE4lhg4ZnM/kIsOhA7u5/5zsNsQpYIoajE7/UHAyn0e1c//HhI0243GOKHZ1@@4fN8d3r6fIo/z3YAX56fn09f/ZPb5vMGzCbd9w9aeQo@HjzEfhk4tf5P4ZKtWtxxxaIuL3b@Nb5//P7xAMH0E7lCUdyTfTSyJpjb02HP4kj5/kiBP@HIIH@CQB6Vo9MziDIgwn4WMITgPaJp@joE1kkyGUvEDqjf0fR7G@eQut5JEgVBN6aTfVtJaV264vA2m7LeToLA1XQl6HB3ziJ0zBiE7Ri8V4oNme0427bZiiJHeO7GLQ0au@vhWIrCIYkcDYtErB49eIHFJG5X6AgfoIq9kr3UF@oD4JryJvH0g8sJRX3ALmf40ePA@dF3hunF7jiMl/rwwdbzhhk0zEeMHGeyIwPsCfVMYfZw/b6B8C4f8a6xXJk57MClatY7VvISWZkMMpBZFhnxQsblbhF8hESLCqjNESIlEspx5aziP1hgvamISSmUynnIg1JIJLvFdm6X3sNHZZHqfRS9duGIgSiMBYMTThFwDAjoINJDcHsn2F@a9xBIH2Jxukh2nQEKLFQ/ocSPRDvjHX58gOwYvcjLqgGIrdI9Vg3Q0aNdrF0HZ/jElQAW4tqRsYmMsfqA99uth88euXvwoi@OV6YHp6JTFNq4jdq4oDGsU25JRn7StwSHnEFms5lgYx/80LQnlnefZw1nx2wY9Uwdmf7JidVU2gl16eG9X/Cu5MkvJ999x3@v3U0eTryTlInvPt8EhsqxR7JAjszUJAXiod1JDyfmnc8nPaQm3ksPfoZRGIyKZ0q0mG147bpBzZUU0II9Fwyvf3WnBH6pPPgLd4oPSJ76j25TKz@XYvwL@Epgasj@pxRr1wPKNFMrn3LCncIXb5DueE6C2eDjTnaicJaxR06t7riHFPBDhow@XwEqA3Qad7LP9@CFwmVIfJ3xRP7uO84nny1O5EDAi6G@D38q3JkQePCl8POxhztdfFrdTSH/sQfuKShG9gLxkM/m9fOadqDvBHhstemGdIvGBSZvAeRNUqmj209Ht0epjx9Xd4vA5MFvsf@Y2UgDJn6BiT/Z8kz1HN160QuWkEVPj@sX0vEvgkcGcvklnw@Y7Ne2cloUHt1CigZjt031M9aX5PBNZ/MdS5jtTWmdVUZONSKr6uSMUIOci2z2sV855E0bvCTZ4NYLAZoEs2IOn@bpR4qqBDgCgdPsw4Bx4v3i0yfKKdp29YOSsXLpCYjDs2tyFqSOV2DJwdLW6yxf06/71LCjc9dzykbpNo9g/hqObXVXoppIhzN0/g6DYDXwhXk@sTSW5eAJyoZoD4Ah2gPDBbAWwUyy9YQNmbITobWcBoJcWE@I1us8@FAsA@snUG@bng8qxCIDOvMeMiT/KEV0E8iTBCEknZLyIABdhfoAlcA04DpID@gMFBn67jtkP56mYE4ex2MBBsNwIx@LgV5RCoV/A6WAA1M5AhnF@pAUArR9wCnYLXmnoMg/riD7rQIPZPCN/NbLBUHycoFnqhjWOzWYb16LDNwWHz6MfKmITRD8k6kC5Ie0598d2MP9McpWr2qtZr5@lW7AFeY6ic15w8frk2lfnUep4XMme5JCnHB5rs4K3QseTBgwXE18bBE@d7qPLlplFApVcn58yACw/sBa@4IB9XiNSTDIAW5GUNUH9FwaS/TugfX4jGDi70uOxw84BwZjcsjgLG/e9Nm86GPglS0YzO03o3eOLJ8IhmEfsxlwTi4np7OTd54m@NUd6IX2sZzElcrxBiG@R3jzwU882nRpIJHjqIcWgp385ARF08pO@geFj9PscyaHJZpKJhjmGDF@HGCdQMgJhJ1AxAlEnUDMCcSdQMIJJO0A62BmLcwwMQ2HY5tgfBNMbILJdTDCbIIbDJHQJhjeBCObYHQT3JQWWZcWSxC86MDhJum6go7T2EjCScOv@CkmiYwCGvZlZAQIDb2ChOyRV5FQXmI3Mp5k7IJKdBUDhUKxzTNoHwc25bGo8lt0@K2SrSc7EsYqypqoEYHN6zpopfwCnx8MQuc9RvjNBYoCtYt4WeDAGBBMsFJSBZB/wXtsvdGnL483by9gDCl2/QzZ8fmakIclR2Fb4rMnObQv2cIW2ovNepcSrRmz9eqHTaRF5fHOSGthjOzEbWP9iBUs5ugbECELArfB7rsiTplNfbq3yPD7Re4g3FvkK6IsvNF9uTBvPAR5yslKxn@CLeWUZ9kpAmltMAPs3z0gMvCiQfGrnakv7LHrt7/6i/8D/fZXf/ob9NNf/eb/@0//Mw7/R3z5P8FmQaE1wJ/8Kb78W3z51/jyV/jyZ1uZCHz42PXTX/waHv@nf49@@oM/tZL@1V@7/JE1IkjBUZucf/7P8OUP8eX/cvmja8A//2MLEGdx@Z@pHdPKA1B/8l8QgtIwljWyv/gbhFw@MDA8tuTdWX38YetFMAvBmg13JPTwMt268kMds53x@lyA135iN08@3ADeLeQ6hw/y3/Q9MGcsB2SspXmOH@KXfewo1cD2D49NGNUIDkDe5n0weuy1DTfU/r9Hx8jtwzAQTd5oTVk63K6/XW/XJhXD@lw0UIfPxrVR4bB3TQlMbymQbzITWBpBPG0hM1LWkhGbvxX8QyHOAOJyJEsyPayXsstycsOkB9nnrcP/ZqqLhRYPQ9YboeR3Dyj7vRV2q8AddfOi2aCUlzEwZdy8I7adlUQIEw2aBLKt@Y0Zix8IF/wv0W1azu42@WrhRYfBnx6YmONtjbQuKIVcrq/AYk7b8F5scYV34S16bYA75jj8sPPG2T5g183NjYvaimOwDOl9D8GwVSlLZayT2N2k0FZSaCsJaLZwEl0TDYVe0EAGDqwXd9@utLJtqajdbBvhwj3HaQdMBswFrTVNvyhPjWHqNWqikXeV3WvkWyjZh5TdT@4VonPOkMv7KgPg3M2TetmW@1Ezr2BeN9T@nJjbOzE7rfU2pp08W52CcI96yaV1y7HJfS23W@A7qNkH3zcWFGL@kQUFvrGgWPTrBb1sVpx3B/3b/P262nHUxFrDb5BZHf9gZ4DCQ@NfgOht1BGmWCdBjxemPGl7ytObq8iz52B9iKedU4V2TtPXt84awpOYimoK1vLAZ02FKYeKreCtX@PZ94ta9o/fDBRVF4ztN0kl660cxY3fZebVgQKjmh@fbiTZPxWB99qt4y52x5X1yGZboVnrB34waotR2PJ8fJQUyXx8BONTFr0bBuLHII9flXBT@JeBILSV37M2bauaR8WntJner@Mk9q6VrSnxY09VsxPdUEgawYSOF2SYfKEhx4/xb1wRluAqkvc6sUXaMz1ezMShOlEHgqLi17hx7hfoSxvcmCBO0wgtfsT5Eb9FkT2J9vB@zmtnvfzZWdFlyMN51/lDuwh2mOFH@kseY87qe4p7fLM4K5tTXuPn09vYprfxPr2ipBvmS5pJJF7twfefV3TYs8EAgBsywl8nw2@f3PCKnB1S1tH4ByusDN9MYl8weBj@MKVpAE3b4EER5MO/fjLgaU14@y3@v9@ATvb8tzYfMWYbS9A3kzy2/cgUzSAH3ii84AHwkhfrntfFrUU7941l2RMdMsPzIxdRXAp@4wY6pqYJirHea3YQf0XmsRPQK7knnkEpK3EPTfrMj8aht5so99gXZG4p9D02pH8Lr1PjusD1ib76topjRUeUnmr9SomH8bM7phh5M5IAHb8hMpx/5vW@LVYWiLSWHrIZRygsvc0/snD3UjXjRdCUtQei6qBBD8iRKOQgGm2pLa23qWXrx9FsPWqNP1ZLVvBL5l9lCPDB@ukr1r8p1vue@qx71lX6hhFhDRvcrTJ@YdLBiF9ZfN2GP49FX68pWWVYZ0o5rbxjnbzV4tJ7Lb4lFY5MWlbJt4nk14Tum2VuS9QsZBsVlv15Q8grzFlOlnnes43Rinm3xVTllU7AcbjFVOWNUeVxj0Jd5ySazsSnzKcs@8JLSRAswX0G9zbcMUKYgz5aAuXUDdu1zpIXSZlw2pbVYsfc8dgW3eKid3sfcQuKcsJ4Ifd5XSb/Zpn8qzL5nTLXPWC3yC0git8p0m4F3DzvNYEsiOYb2hkn4Zk73N5T2/BRVE7He69f3JL7WPIj98x9DArZLbiP8x5Qyu6@@zhHAob7uEECY/fxJQQ2fcv9o/vY6RYYQIdHEviM420Vjp9593HW432myE9iOuUG3cfrNgWYT9Yj4ciztbzas3f91fWqqiD4LaPSj7DEGHBTcbXuHvzky8A/AbXPGYPEjykUOiLAeAKyM2hsjRhWOTBsBMlv7nn2DR/HztKUvb6xWUOBdF9qa1EFS8mU6CP3gXtXGVmE4VSy@Ah3IBDrzeP9FCH21czsa@TYpYOEkkbeLZ9wL0jsgb6HpN8B8PYijrzJ77TXLgqrAb@NTpz5LTpfkeMURyjCzgDePWRhpv7gfqdSuK1fnFlltf52C71eI8CNGHBArFYiaLd0Othw2DYlhWmqtiskJBXv9knbefDH7pRYel9kI1rB7plvJJNou2ZYMWx3fu971dnKh0nbUUE48Y55sHrZelwguhgnbXTdlqVqdT4gYUvn9MlxEwIW25wdJHCWuvGTseKtYcjJaxVJNNeumoTMQfy63JQzrdI3@zL4JbqfN311coIJDjRiBFs516VY@lX9Gfa7atnvjkHtMOFFAfsM6/1D6Wvz@t1R9gXl8qbY1w2IE/0o591rHK1L2LAcZgdblvl7svbKxMc/PmQZ@Vaha@wvrH2Hbes5wVf49nJuYeHCVoI@240c44XZcehtRr22SORZ0DFagrgkG49V8TWlm6q9T6tV8X1NjFPwGA23n93A@m4DbzcexkcqoL9gudXL8Y84kn2Kdd/Ga@pbOxfWroOKvcTWJ7BtRYK6J/5raxctiKg@1nPVSrkLg248Hve@3orAvRbybsZx6t1tgvW0JeTHx@2Qn5bGvhNDVTc/3iuu1y5lJAKMAY7s21jiZ/dxr63LtvT5i74L@SzYLY7auMabbsDtaCVs6nB4yJZsvloHX3uOOBuJY94Cv/1ktoZ3jbB04A2dx0cyfD0@Yuecx0d7FMNNs95G@t2B/dtXoa3fhz7Y9WYiFpfx6kwLvAAwnVi/TmwvwNmnVVh@KAf4l8BNJ/c611QxJcfZAa8P4S2qtWeEJ8x6rR8Qd2Ks3/kGSfWEIngKG4rit4@tXBgaL3wS10q7nI@WoYOPYjU0VbF/CHxs/Vg8ORjWcJZeCdlTZc4RNxCrFPLS9BZFlkOWsy9GftuXHDVu/ZAyp1hLyA5v/EgYBMmOTygJU46xpFmnsa1dPwwvyUQIJj5awOOeLEzw7@uC7O5ZTb6SoFWGBWkwAEGi7dPcLQeXJv7J3YAqBrLOKSMHqE1@Jdk@xdL2CSMnyNrrwMBOz84xMQYKxcCaSvqBs5svMBa7ySB8FAxDnLQIFHzjcItbwYR/K@9Hz9K7e2edjxfj@@h5xC1rvW0p6fjk9hmnbPHZfglza2na3rQkemBr59I58YiyT6hKkX3KIPZR0zyuA5dzDhQOWm4TnMw7B6h48NE9x9QHhSge7AGGeMu3BgxcBRttZHvNu3ZJVdAvUDhEfooSyiNWKikWcFg7ezvYIQ2yYmIt7z5bwbh@0Xf9Am8mUh8OsC60ZA3nd0QZh8l5lhtZRh9tdNaGCu7KVhdwHqJbD2GYanzYU/BHj8sHWHwur2sHE8Dbux8fLM37OisoRe/v6GY/1imo6XS6OWH1@nl6kB6m6114zjBlX2cUydN0vij307lSb3muxpszMcQ0u9eZXthXi/cXmlScZItanpIi3YnvNrxIFiOraDacTfPMjXheFiPx7I14YwhpWUjSs9H4ui/UtR6rG9Jl5apSX9GF1nV7cD0SbzudUVxpUFr9NjO4XgjXiY4ya7eSJeNaaGcr5rgyMqfsshrvxFpzxci0m5nhxbI0Hy9KMbUrRbPXQrwtasU5v4xqfLFF3c6aw1ijuBwn2Ul/mc4a/W7c56O72cwgUeT7t@JFI3vZH@jRXnTcSHLh2eRC1JbDy6LyVB5lGzPep40KpdiMUmql2VyIdMY9uajc1tvtXi5Tm49Z41brjyKdq6nZS@ixcHiaFoajSLQ0NfVEOZO@jJu5dKldkG/a5u2ynahRZtFsxlsXfFL2zaomH57mWrTBtBcX0mVjHiuGmmpRuZBLo9r4fHpek7XpOBeRqs1JRB/cFHpqKFS8bsyK3TKlRy463UR9FErk@AVPX0ZVdRJuJitl/WoxzTxVhU6Wb2SEXozJRG/y7OiquuSrs3K93qlpndYkblyy8m2BGVHVG76RzowL5UmCbVaWpcR5qTHNZkuLWS8kDtT0tN8JX93E5uWKUOpc0@EiNzWvfFK2KtOjiwtj2W5dlm4qxi1066sLKSIuF5l2Rhefclnjql6mK/p42IiMlL7WjktZlb@olSJmaZwuzju3yVJmLIi13lgdNztyZ2pKuRFdoJbZ8XWrJ8wL0mrO5SPl9jU9ytd5M54ehBv0SBR7Y7lqrAbn5dWgMe0N@snqOZMTni77mXa0ntfYq4IRqShLqtvMiNKqfi2y41qyWLrt5dPSlRLN1gStdl6cLUKhriTW5tEVu7gZFSLSgo8w5Wrm5sp3fRGq@8q@TKamhqsDKpQrnHcG0UufWhBWdFnknuJZnz6dRha5Kf5F5XJLkfVJVGYShaZvGDf0TvLqat4zSjf1bIeXV4nbq/E4dlunbmYlQ9VDiYtCOknXxox@zo0qpdu4pBQi88y5nE@WOqtWwsyXp3KiWB7kLup6rjnhb5L5QWO5HA8SF0KtPE5TQiJXr496g3Zv0W0YtSVzFeFHPV/@PF95GkA/bjcKoYtWJjaY1sPty5wyqzULvpV60ylr2cqYzdcS01gzHp5Qs8VFIt0wFUnLnV8lY9dTqZxP5watLKsKws0Tf8mOuUZzySSMuH5duLnWDJ/Z7KmR3jATXl5fden2rWFEixJ1u@jESumxzl/2F@aFEW8qIbV6zbDXYqUlR2cd6albU0fpCX3ZulnRvfmqsKiZvNkYq9F@PDo@XxhP@upSv6QS3REntypZtTziY5ddaRWno6zS7GbFK757EWLSrUHxSigUZ4NVS5iERsWnaZHneKOW7vbO5dhsofnEcGJWppqVzs0g/vTE9IRKNymlx616rWSGmhw97TbK0ady1zAKfKskZSKSMs1luufjSfZ2yTWNxWrajPVkcVnTQ0yeWlS6V21@pA6MgnHLj1Y3hVvlahqK3VRHYtzsj9mJxJbbIhOvaHVfzleTz3uDZaw9FWY8WIbadUljM@nRqEpV2Ul8llkmDVM5Ny4rvexFWkqny4nQtRaKF8fZ8@KiL7Vb7Uqxz6mR2142HKv2Bkyon6nkB7XIZBCvVeKRcpZq9pbXdbafS0jskJOzo4tlREuWQ5kY3Z7Xi9ej5lCpyNl0ZyFmwnxTncc7nKi0hFUsTl8xvtEweaGkmUgtRrXMnNkqF@Zhn3JZugrVlkv@psdNw5z41DV8fHc1XFXbAqfKw/JTnW22p@WsNBq1Yxm@yVQzDWa6MuacVq5RyVxNYXPlxawwHzY6jKHlilqit6j0s7Wa0NP6YU3sVdMLkZl1OrfX162qMrm5nhTr8V511edG0bYp1mPVhUk9gcnTnpVbhd4iJxriqD57Us4X05s2HWmdT8qt/sw3St52Z2HppsqUK5m2yE1L14O42aostKsLWZTpSag6oKl5q7ZamUJazVfmV92F2F6t0lLGeGIXlzRXPi/lbkxfMl9I56rNBqfL1ep5OZfmJvOrefkm7hNWjat@VBo/3VI1RZFD@m1DjmeYsBFqRXOrLD86Z6bnmUnzoplkNbZVbF9dXbJDmZ/w8W41F@tc8Z10@uJyeSFy7VpNq122mlTVp9zc3jbpalMuJ8Vyqd5Uo6WZftXpxLm5mr7mmFJk0puXF5n51XTamSQvfF1T4MLqShDY@lwu00IRZCdBCdNZLVupGcvQ02r0NJjl1Jt2Mq2dx9LZpdifCbMVk87NfLRRWMz7MUlLhJrdxbnY5a8Gg8t6ZhjWZlozlo1SF0nxSmn3ssOr5FK4LJbbhakpNPq9iOQzGG3UvE63jBa/lM752HDWMroydD5RizYz2aQh3@YSl7rkYxJ8huI7V1yNLg@jN5WLvjrPLq7ayxxMORKsWGOi6lJpTxNjpXhpZC47T5eJxKDVK46h4OnwdshLLV@m3xOuRblC3d5ctsf52rRNj65vruK1VtGXWIX18ydeHZ5zyWVzVWUYQUwOZqXpIqyV@cR54rLKyxeLSr0lCoNYI3QtnysrKqfEh0xaZOezuUL7ltFMIj8QM62KoudafDEuqDWOphedW7PauUlchs6Za6YxmTMh42pOM2JXkZbdSrcb6lOZmXGpdRrsLO8rmuluY1Tnz2W60qmXVuqynA8ZrXQlK15O50utvJT08C1fPs/KNV5iwSyJxgZNvTVeZWY9qiMuytlMIn4bKoIEGYacnHcjnMAb2mAxostX06K8GE3Hbd03WdB13213EU0O20OD5svlZqU0z@tR9cIYKVQsxoeKHV2LG/WnybKUNXPDdkuOZJPtQa9a7NJXTfEyeZ1t3MaFaI0uPQnJTiPG8OVoh6fZujqZmTAi8YMxVV4yfZ2XBZ2LT6tP0fx06usvZ1PTp93Gzy8TncE4y854zhdO99QnbtG@kBmpEhcGRrUzn90UOmAhKu1ZS6EKty0tfCkVxUaxXb0as7V0fWXSmWSHv4kMujorKuKsHjajFyVhEOfFXP52PMoVS08lpis@MXNW1q@vw4UiS8VFX8ZU@zLdvtaulVWIE9LdauJq3l9lJ8OKKBRLoZzercf6jUtOzsMwKj2VGa1dOC/f9nvykBZVpdqoMwx1GwvlOzf1J3bWv66tmuqiqA8u0jU5fCOWFLV202Zz1zpdiWcK19lR/Ta7TMRqutwTmoNEU5n4zsMqz6WVcoyKCzMh0@7QLUEKs/HFqseNBZq97YzHiSK9ihkrOq0Y81FisEr2zids57ainjeXY/p8sritZW7YqeBj2RqvUdfmqhY9P@/4LpfnrdJAbpVEnuYmy5FRzEyFi3nvOpb2JTSm6cv328NFuTbQOnk63usl2EY43ImYT/3a0riuUO1cuRiO55bmQsyPp5VFoqilY43lonUdiYxvR4tqohGrRxfsTB3nM1phEKXVGyOuLJrFQSEj5MUr0bha9fgJFVtNK6VCIu@LCly31r1lxDz91OjL5nAgNi9vwo0YzUeL1dr89jaXpidxcZQvyecwJs65q8WyMeqOe9dVIyxRarXrK8VWsVXj9rrSV2qdi6thbz6Ix2t6sT1KTlddrS7VfdqqVeqp57naRM6tbkDgYvVkdNSS862OdJOrM1XKjHXSc7DB2UxZWg7oUpS5FBXmYjE5T95MOrFxd9zOzurdxXgUa8Sj6lRYxc3OU3QqtOLdi0mD5nvd@dAXOqfUxmp5k7@O6OXKXCubNVW4ZBKh8u24NclPW75J9rLQM7MdRuuFOuX51JeNglWQuGonQ5Xe5ShTGp9fG8XrUJJqFqTlNDE6j537ajCYTEdGNdGWQ/KM7tByez4TxhOGq@S4tr7otQrlfqUfStCaT4rPzcvY00W3dsuZWkShKWMZ6885XzEPFkRO6kYbvrapMROYizA3s/ClMgiHDOWm0eDNrBoft8JJIVLQ24raXqijdki6Po@P57x0OaIywqofkVv1Tr@yWM37yXGkzzVmrXThRumEs4o2XBg6G0tehtrcU22ih6umViu3@IxyPeE4ce5byJncld6YUf1BJd3vFJ6m4qwdqaYj6eVNn4lMb2cjVlnd5LuhUa2XHorzeieyqs/Dmf45q9QnkjbRQzTTbCv5cWLRKgqX1MUqLyyHietMrR1pXY6S47A8GDdqzHJclUT@9taYsqXuoHzN9kvRduY6OS6KRlqIt5LixYheVHrV21i2L0QYyjcsTehQtsyHL/I3PvOCl6NP0oqtmKukqCwrLanXGMzSWrk/ak0rmSKdYUOz80V1Ei7W6fCUy0wSuUu9q8uUkI@mF63qVcwY3qbNdkSthWYJ7bYmDW5C/dqQ4ydMLAE6@Krfu1220vXMvNytFBtGWhmsBJ8@v1TOS4VCRqGKYqfyZDxxqjhNR1rVcvf66TqtD5rRnmmU2MWTQC@XSvUiy/PLbrpkjCvti4ZSijOTfuYqfj3sl5WWWpPClxSfjI9v4rTS4C@mjBCppSOFp/Y5/1SaxerqWDH5Zv6WNSt1UHalaKuqdeeTVXbIiItwJH9jVAd97RZ662hFhabFerdfF0fKYl6/MNuX4UmDHbfn8jimcJovkk9Wqxw7CONJWPRGVSaqfDkwbxqV2aVO08NVbCpo58KlRJVD2iBdqscuQtz5eTeXbLGTp7IQSlxFpul5qFq/8ilRQcuVBhOZyY7rI@FagilDJ1YbXTCNitQa3E6zN8llg1p1e2JSuejM1cvseJ4bz0bN1iIM06tmu2wYjfqN2S/NQr2LuNyrDvvNXCF7zWc5zohXlWy@Otam7d5kXoxEqVEhfDO6il9Ig9g4XhKW3cuplqxdrErZYTHi6yoXCbPLmfJTVR49VXqm2XuKS@3G9QXdycR5hXlaxs2bYYc2qGJikj@PCPFVacjGW8pkNp32q3VFLS1r11fA5ngo3Dzv0Wmtc10z2/2iwN8UW2DpX6hCqXFzoTXOb4r9aV@h5DCIb5bWL8/LRuEmN75l56X6siexvnH1cl6NxqNisuebRSeV4TQXjXbik4vKrJDT9NjiCrT@oLaslYV65YpiJ1fd/Nh3IbJsQr9atWeRelq4ifWu5uI8Es2lF8owkWgxi@uLc/460dNK80nrgh1c0/Pb5NiYcC2unuZVsUplnrTwMrcw80w0fxkr3lwLo9i8n5@GSul5o1OKmcmK2OlEnub1@VioFFixuZjNQ7VC9dpUItFF@/p2fAmtEKX4weI6HxeuIkKfkVa3Wb2g9pQWl2boCzo0b7WvfepAeaoIvnEtVAhrsTyzqHEwM77NTC/6sV5rJHfOM8XkkOpH@LyvacRKt7Gnm6crSb8Z@eITUDkJsT67vgKTpGe2mpHFtZjssqt2NtHheoUVm7@k05FicZoshUIX5WS5SxmN6ASk5WkeurnIyaHrWrsZmfpyldyiP2zcturZ@VXitstOap3G7AJPxsI0Mxero3prWSksWpIQy4/reTFD@UrXc6Oa1MR6rp3X6VpfLERG4@J54VyYXvLTRV7xMYNSazl7mk6ExMWVzAm6UqibwzQf7ibG4QVf0tJPl21qWeTyF2w20U7oY4m/GFVaxsiYdTRRSkeeogufWR/VpMtort68UUatYaWi89mrUNwQcuPGJHbbGi16MyHfv6BEMznj5cV5JWYqmWVBumldXV/0G8ySryUuKgV9wfTowlODmZl0K9GoNQe9ii6VRzBw@rotVU3IoFLMoXpNcdqwxMzb6ct@YmBkz5lE@WJRbUkVH3Odr49yIWOm@@jhpBrKrdT8RVicxwf168sJo2dn/aHvshanb0cZdV6homY/3OGMcbIust1um9by9ZVhXCVaPd/ltUwL9dBtPFNcsc1eWOtPh91Ed3I@e@p2r5567UYRmvPGJ8QaV0/U4PqyaMTFJM/2W5lsOa3ONOZCn9TFyKSsdluhrujrLnKl@VPokimMSj22UhmuVhn@Qu8oidykd5XllqNWok2F81WmfxsWtItW7qlbGE5HfLa84MM3atHw3UQqi@m5nojH2Ehyxhnh9mTS9iXSsuSLh4fLYSiTn8VydF@vd6h81ZftqCr0gvptjKvQRqRfkU2jFW828sl6tpAtli/zN2I52ShxNze@7nUpm083YxeXw3HksssaGTpzNRw1QtSonB33adNMTKWGVDDy53puMbwdX0@mvXl8Vja6K@WSm0qDCSty2rhTVuKx9HX7KVplwvkrOn@7kpVQPLpIUn1e7F/Qcn1800lI@SLdlYcwgc6B/I9vrqY6L@rGMNmBml@tlHi2VR209aI8rAGFcm@q8eIkKY2HQviWqtONRCHekS9FvtqtT@LdnnTTvAjHxekC5q/d3OpSzNHQ6q1uYzhlbmJ5MF0jkadSZzi5nlXaRj2aazfLtQjVfqrnRLaUL5fbt2afrVSZQWFmtuKJYp7lJ5lxJb/M9DKleYFvdYq@kS/U7POzQjst59t9zlgsb5kko6fFERUbxa4yYo4159G2qEeyF8NqmJNL6qJ6kdAm9dpFKHORvxbVsc5krtPOJ9ZeJidSdDkQ0@nzdqmbHVDp62xuFGqLBl9XfPMSAcsUZO53P/uoEEHXFQJGzVSpj8hvxNvHXJy8c/AEOXkCv96@c@4EdvbZPkhAtN@vBlqgHL@rhd8QPrYKIXubQfyDCXhr8eTl3mKAdY4TIDd8jgc6Ij@SIO5shLp0nHlNxkdJeY8AsuNJdlDwPhh5PfkXxjF8gQa/gxLYRN6o8xDeeL9KG@EIPucDn9DJPJxsbXl62G1qMIHQZJwiAj/9rl/gUxW@g4xkCzhfLXj3beszJzv5gThDU8hJI65A0EWy2qdiYEy7KKzWxPHrsxkociCLs7H2zk9AcTSbYGJJcr4HUvymf3KXfPAf8SkXEkyJUybGVJ/3xwN1OBORjLRRb8EvV08IRSMoDGWFvrMO8GRjKZqchxuHawIlGftoKuv8THJWEj6gixyziI/rdCMUWB9v9RF5ScCPL8euk1dSio4mjhRah3xM7mIPKSXFnEzulIcTxefzmr6U6WN9HhzxHes90aa2J@Kd@UDe2qeP0JXzaj3@gQTs@6uKqKYq/FB1G4j8QPP2OyfkIDKnA004bbs/zQTeVPXtGBHLEzfZ6Yivo/AuMfcip6Q6cOZSE/DW3fpUAhn/tD2@fJjGIiev03ENP3zAR2ic2L4T2xX4QmnTnizxx9QHwk@8BY5fpz8@tg@F4RGW2w8fSJxkRVq0IMnw4OQTJ5VXtaWdWbJAHp26nG6hPPPgvVWv/1sgHageyOQj/jkrHcAsEIu9O@AIUJOtUa9FFQ6XBWW9D4rP8fGe4FNO0EcnzTnxB8NjuSHn7jyaSCKn9MDtFNmg5AwM5LVPnCCxdxJ@6Y24Epy5raQPo@lEI/vPQYtemyP4FzgfNU7S1zmDxhT/krQHsZgZkkM0bgEceMZnwc04U9huGqctsOMbefkK1wfjq5EfXAGCeU7Xl1g34pcPML6@SvJ8sH7i1YNM1XKstMiw85JqeO2mBsbh06rdmvsYET@4E4giW6InW6kjSMV1fSN5AskTzhy@kTzEuKfGW8k6JOMffn0jWYJk653I/ekqpFs7/W8AmNjLE8T10VQfTU6SPdaBHvgokGdLYXuQz@cwdi0CyGoYqz128yP7aBT00WodS9h2xAv6JxErCwCLtMfuPPh5Iy0kFR/m7bHkYqtMiyfoC/pqYbZzJLD4kZQEaheX7z3awY@2CID@B6oUvU53Crdae13RHfkJwrAzwK0NzAqjH398jzJbEHflj31wpM9qIeyHu1VDi1sbPNbvUm7a1cq0sjPtz2MfHbOt3RwfiU09nE4Z2qgQq29t@rUoKX0oAxB/3I7GLk9e9GkTc2c8oOO19tjw0eoWX@dj6JX0YI8o0iP9qLcJ8t/OVQ7LPeTkYETubZQFPieMO3nFTmMNHdiFPgPoNTdfyBm/IzN2L/25lf222hwAfaRTE96cWIqWB9PwzCZwD3mc1a7bOsFCdug@tuLx721Ku8ikN5BZ5@k9AgLzFGjAI5ujxp0xUVKC1jupoOeZUMRPXMwtkOcNmxxl9S18@ifoXJhx9pA9xT9BtquS0B7WvAJf1xvz6@xll3tRPUvT76/cnfVSs/uTG9OIXssTkbpPMEoeIwatD246Qc9f10P/MM582TTfjr1jeN7WFU6jO5L4LSL4/Aajvypku1UIPaAdjmMSiGb4ypBEDiHcPyhtXOsfnRjH7dLq229aYJiqk910TLOF0EkAQ3k7l9@2uc42qtM@ffHRdIwb/8YKw7/8aUkFmOwn1LY6x9O5Ahm8t2PXR0f9/8Vd/1caS7L/OfNXtPiSQAIIJnf3Pr/dIKLyjooLGOMxboIw6myA4TCg8m7yt@/Wp6q7p2cAdd/7Yc89Nw7T3VXV1dXV1TXdVcwRtwQ32WFhjg1lwY2xbckMNu2K3W8YZmEy@Elz@jYMe1ljMGmDgSGYCB1UKS/hrKxZJeZljJ7QaaNX3eooH2bd3aQ3K/oVryv0Asanlk0Q8e6Wp80mpo1j3wQRJ6blcqxGhMrcPsBhRdE@aiP9HrWtCfRqYSOj8RGTjCNXaj3PK3FCPWSqnSEOhmI4ZGu9lcF7OxCos0Mb7Ti@JY/BrwVeBonhqaNb/uluXYLNoAib2A66OQWZ27TUbG1lgMYK/K9/rq6sTaPx2nUwXPOH92RUX8@8VeUPJc3ahppObgq/46BwpXnwWWsTPpfNhxBJTGikgK049B@yqEOWM6KIZnKexKTjQ4tlDzGI@dx437/vkdUvEVtGYfTI/85os1AqTkeTkEs0Io5dp34GP@N4qiW@RaR3DJqcLYYT18nifoG8nclZyUJZDKQyAiznHBCXaMkKN/M1k8H4gVB9nvTyyouKfqd7ByIgez9lO0XDxZL8y4vM0CPWGliByyv02JcoEyM@OwoUbJ1EM/5N3cfvMh7kDR9xhdzrfYrHB4JR0g/DEYQcR0HRfosYIIx/1Wrv1ZrNok5eIyfWccpdzjHjiiAHrOPcC/YYL06rI1ygDMordBawBd92DJz1L/MIaDWbMBUewE7hFeIRSg8KZf411w1bPyfVmSV83Un/isDLko7qMSI7CryLm2WdZgXTzFR2WPHqWW50ul0Egjj2ByFRXPX7fSJaePEqZgcewRGD/73FH10C55UlXsoLc@WFRHlRyoWouFaxezeOK224lTKrf8b1fqlMXC0/h2tbUafrJxxdqhiOHbo3n6obFWmTFsSVd@xQilTagq1EQcEp@fuC0ZeSlUQbK@C2/FLKtXyv65G3VCbqfkrix19PD5DPMRj0lcWUlBaHQf8PcT/aEtawCmGVpDnGm8VOJqV2iGh1UiA1QULM03ZnO4byvmw0Ds@ZzM7Wp0xRu6T@yKbJkKxrcxNrwRxxuMQ43zPjHnklITxcvOKAYJgQNGVm7o5pPNONZw5Y1FoxaD0TKTQ5walr6Sm@jWPdP/GPmexJ4ky91cWFr4TyR@m83LRIMoiV7kpmMZuS2mQynvryUnfqiVUkxj1LQ1ysJE5C7EC7d9AUFqcv90Fuwumwt2L1hKsojKaY47st0ZyOK5SN@C4bQhT@8v659s476AzIKuz7j6oCm7rD4fi9xGWbiR9NIpoDPnVwrKLpaNQPdFw39cDXOaSf5fXfcBkhhugYDUWvjguiUj@PJ305hhoVVQOQH3DPMC6IprfISw1PMFIsk2q9CQjkpOhVhjOOTMxh0NblyouvpojjCgXcp22fQ4SMnMwe9jzASit65mKRdPVG5vdwQiYQdTzkmIcItbrheX@bBt0f1QO1Xir9tVz6UHZYZlzVpeKHj6rumEimYL1ULpV@K3/0vGo4msnVxmw3B1gfCwCYV0dY6D@TbPr3SIHsVWjF4IoRmf6RP773e0XPa/o99gFfT5kjEOVp5EsUZY7zijdkWyHePZm7gyivaNt1B/WCv1ifJXZtlwNr5D3cIRr540EwkZtG4X3QAwPNvambsN8PH9gRjStLwg80GvgTYsq7nEqSxHFpNS1su3C4WOIGEjtwAL/r8J7jSGs2kJ0aIPw@XwDyEEQREFxkkubdoYTwdfudYABxWkAAoizFHDAEUNd6067/JA0eE/Fv0qB0x3phd4rIvB0zMmuk/UKeKzTd/XFA2jdmMI8KN3NopwFuH9ZbqtXYb59XmjVFz6fNxuf6Xm1P7V6o9mFNVRunF5yhSx02jki7tFTlZI/enrSb9d2zdoNeZCotapnhAq9ycqFqX06btVZLNZqqfnx6VCdoBL5ZOWnXa628qp9Uj85osT7IK4KgThptdVQ/rrepWruRZ6ymmRe3U419dVxrVg/pZ2W3flRvXzDG/Xr7BMj2CVtFnVaa7Xr17KjSVKdnzdNGq6bQMW@v3qoeVerHtb0i4Secqva5dtJWrcPK0VGqo43zk1oTxCd6uVsjKiu7RzXGxP3cqzdr1TY6FD9ViXlE4FFetU5r1Toeal9q1J1K8yKvgbZqfzujSlSo9irHlQPqnJd9his0LtWzZu0YRBMnWme7rXa9fdauqYNGY4953ao1P9ertdam8o4aLWbYWauWV8i4yagJBnGLyul596xVZ77VT9q0ZpydtuuNkxwN8jkxhqisUNM9ZnDjRHpLTGo0LwAVfOAByKvzwxq9b4KnzK0KuNAirlXbbjVCSExsu91UJ7WDo/pB7aRaQ3EDYM7rrVqOBqzeQgWCCbznFUJ6xr3GOBFd8kjC6hnJzfNwqvq@qux9roNyXZskoFXX0sJsqx5qntNcXvMWfnJ78gPe/Fc@7Qp5Okh8tbFXI4tPMsNk4vdntOj8nvx4lyijhcYW0k/9FZTXqm89/3p6@y0Y3oTYmttm8gV7EN3mkR4ph3ynX70nMjnrD@XcYHX127fPlW@0z219@5bLv6RlgoznWugorE/Vyuk@9sNOj7f5Cd@Sy6idNzrWe14CL7u@ljfW@ZBTa2s9XzfD5UUANm4inZSAgPWgGflWY2eoHJT8iTnpK@KMGWlnkfm8GUb0z/Bn/EPWBucFKWc5t7C2hj0sk4HMJ8rST0g4KYjODMLnAIIbRlmMfP/HbbbkosOWXzuocqYN153QNvA2m3um@bV/m2peSLdnYnHXlI0VEw7ehGmHYIb8S7NM6XEpjrlnWXHt8Z@coYYRkVGYE1R8kVWfPsm@keaILyq@wtymDSXO6UCOK1/q59jMldY/bqbeH9r3Mrdw6xy5bWi9u@R2V/zn8Eoq0AQLsP0ilgQz@aS6tua0IauM7UlbGbHq71DpIejRmoql@s7nZR0R8iVcsNueFuNx8OhST2r4oFk53j3b3yfNCWo//v7bX/@y6emI@@PJl7z8vQAeJLVk7pIV/RCQmcZFziypkt2zP5csx8nug9FDRaSTNIPGLztk0trImWIjSH4NcQOhuxEyDAyRZCODJAHjjML9fH/FM/K6cGZqAcgmuppDbwadR7bwO2QqsQx0JUpmf8aj9oh/ANtOfzPFbYe0AGkR8wejyYwklzYXrPcy@ybgAO9t@FoxqhQzRo5HHXMGSRgDnclRGHAHn39p2XZGkexaDDTmKw87tyQiVtJUmCQtnHKJUJyGkZnB8jKgN1@0vNHjhU4OhCKkeqhMWsTGfduyYJL3iM9ZTwwN@Wpnm4bozRuLaUvBkZrTRIn/P5k6xp0NTIocaFApwObkkeWzLWEn9Ke3OfWnSCqiegPOppZY/Zskd1F3NJRNExJd/zYZZJTAihPK8KsHi8MzVS5MFcvOBJv@X/xg@P9BniyAv0UbToIec4v1cDCc@i/kJEMVXtHulZkSPJgTY84xtZib7quLGMwvd2DubMf0MbxH@bBELNCjMzMvLiSlWHYBAyDk8Gu48xcBfHkS33Vo5/SJ5@4r@dI/HnYHo6xJyGWWijm4V3m2ufLmiBx@5OQTfkk56I6QX@UTx3lknYENF2mx65l6HWUExvsy6xx0eu0dOz3sLGfRBBvKZobH4lTSU8tM/kd9wiheZXqm9BeZosuTfdnPIcgplFD45guIUSB89sntsGYb4dwBoQv7jUgv7OVXehVHtkpSgbwuqzaH54g6N7xnxlKkY2kgaAdQAs7rns7ZdO1PHrBc9AU6xxCJoansaw5jAiTaF2nNCKN8c0XiOi@yD5Z6dlNCXi31Z8MfQ2RS9sXFZWoUExmg3BCsRXXc4WRQ/Zf1OxMjfw@27iTx14ccV6Ur3yvhmuOdO2HBTv91FHOELM4HWJe0DsVc6nR/4GXGyGjwUAge6Q/jKuiem5xGtGfgjHWLjP5fSzcEkJXUGViV@Tq0TqQNWci2XxvzBU8yd@3TBZ60n3mbOkXE0RscmNVmEEiG3YRDmvOzjelLhNXB4dMNspweHorXnemgM7zpDIL@jE@d/iO8G65Fw2k0Ko5mXiaTSXoDEQgcIVKI9omvzoNhL3yI1C5NBziSWidnrdOk48/xfFXF86XU/xAOtcuYvTnwN4iZFIU3Exoaf1PNdHLxcezuYT@h9rSwW2uGFwhMNWYBIrwDaxkfnJypA3/oj8kePOUzl@oo6PpDUh9kTPEpzOhONA2q7wN7S2NX@7Bd2LOzqfyAnTrWt@dpBBpaHqKVpalIBI91WkX45mck6o5PsDjf4bhfPeNUugtHOhoQnKYwNsXFeTPt5z3kbjyvtw@xGZeNOftmaFkzvj74EsV0Goizljoz7gwnM2KKl3beENnP@W6KioMBEURvOTt5UzdAJvYe3H79iLqKzPBaC/AKQlPVD@6RLI7dcC8ZIz5nq91mMd82dXzFvKSvM6ojMXpePHp55Awt5tVv/63aPmRXnfY7XdphqdYUzT98IDtwN4wmqHpcUaq0Xi6XC@UPcNGetSpFngj432QQ87z68Wmj2SZG6hD5RjDsmgnmc9IuOY1F7CggdRf1/jsUsqlPGnP9OzMPJriJ45vZlC8WmY0MjX23A3cv9TBKmsPskoVLPhxz4jBEgyIRSkxHwoqgB0jRx0oSmBzoeU5dppOPydJi6eRoftzgO2jrk1z18T30Ozfmd6QA/Ed@R63GvDPo6bD3NCYDf2CpDyZmde9IBS@d88wyTHypJBxv829hJRH3ci6cno8zEhGyBwyi@@6YdEvnnkQOR1hMSCySGdZNOdubznXQD2gOEF3duxALjqgrMxDsgnAzonk84jbXDhYkpmVBtgKaXb1wYKsKVZ5ng8Hp96No1g3V6i1ts7HTika@3@NMCdORpAJAeZFmeZ9WDgkTtxHnCPBWS3xuckzKBilZSPdN@4gdi1h/1zLmnukNSZUJL9i@w7ZeAFGPWhOepMjYll2ww84rfOfN8bB3SCDQNgdGLAn0RyBGeXyUIqpovFkg@InFJY9wVH0e73QcQDTkZETRKFkAWPJV108WGPDou36cqyBCum0JSIUYNMRInCx5TvjAkj/QX5w7RdC0rPSROjfLWWbuB0ihKb6BUN2G@BeVi4Zj8o3Q52@Ec4ELHxGSl@Cla5bna1Itm0DEqbm@AGZhIcwPi2EWNEz9sbI@vOeAbWjFYiG9kGjQIelHMCLu/kFoVC@HleuH8oHJ9v62H14jbxNpCsKGP7N8PLDua96BJRjtlkoQwWS@qS3TJU26vttkbBe1RfPD31FbxmOx83UoA6ULtmUuccwyxWsXTyd@xD96RvFjJpG8ClZHKnsVyJO3pLsBNqNB6jeZDRXPTJzEcetrzMkmg0STcqqJJi7Z5DrRZN2LI5WmRhctoPrxN9kzY5fwqSQeAbVtB6jkDTqPsrspcQA6dtMgZWQiIt76lRYQVLzsKhvTDtWvvDhEc@KzveAwP/kIHp/4zvxXhlNelZL5Dh7N0T1WA1wrUT7jMODDrO5QTrOBf9jwzzlDjO7XFjcZOprKdlgKvES3x7irlXWx5DbU6qgjXw1RK8LC5qK@ZB7gK32G/nunshpBwSVWKiGsrlaFxHgOvXxJW1kZFqMHS168MvMvR8HRCHqiv/nImCwD2WxiXhnNbWHK45zuJlB4L@AYkyfxPyOy6@QtVhRHNbRg8CGNqTby/EfanvE3ZgbB64/1WOuXEtPYag9N/GWM@cqsGsleLK2dXkoW1XFWFcuFpyobZls@La28fLVh1sGHAH0n1R3WHcFJrFlnluC3kbCMrZRgwsFOw24gGirJNkfpStv8AgWcHHJDXD7VK88JZa57mF5GvMTKmRCSrPMLadrVa0lkJ4ByXqIV@L9swHHc0Z3YS@uVpZ4e9mUSYWGZcX9KLGxlM@5PiYVUdob9abEwuQwta7l9Wi4SIyEswKFEvWNgn5Krg0zBo1vrMVWLCZpdubHM/X52AbWOVtW@Tm/OVLIs0qlLkjj4z6MMzKoONJoQR2LepR2Nq7i3tMZ1f/g9G5FZ995ukXYyySVBRjOdiACdNhh4jK5ySJltG5DGFieY3jMP5OwmR7R/KxsW3oMia9ftXfJ2bwKsWVVKuXmD0kTvj4nfWkh8YT6LQrzF2pjPD29Pl2mqceApHPdQO@Mt@OLrPUPVe4eqZO@cEUqyeAmkwosgFV4Aac2BpCf2B1ov@XF1jDx1/nMgvn6dh8F//k4bKQ2DNG0vgBMb@@CHzuw5mCtkbK3ymbqOnCqzDWI7@TkYf6RhcF7QO/s1Tr@868Dr9r/@OExn5VjK2aSsLKDIUrU6T1YeZLHW5v2urmdMJd7bFn9c3wV2J7D6/EhLHGPdGEeJ7@xHoNVkVH0LLJ7/5SX8yzvDmpwPQnjCDUPWsvdvTociGCEeJrkqZhs4iiy5D9UFSUY8XZpWfrxbTUc/RsLTpc1yz/bkkzh8HKdTmbomGishcWYLFysns1oZ/bZoe/Ys/tWF@EfhiGycm4UEcP0B/PjilEqp9Ng0TW2tX7SWLVzP5vvl2m2p3CQvn@Rv5rq@Tl3HxXSa1EP/Qa/@T0HWfTEj8H@w5C@NjCwh8vVCIvGhvaOdW2o4HVz7Y@8lU11aFPFH9kjLJdfzVldVpUtbZh0ZH16xLqfv8zVKmMEQhEhNR/heE8nhTkxu@Mh8EeB03V74MOTaxQxQsI924HeGOlS@XjBvx/h@Yevmkb4Tl7sYQzDsEqMj33F/fpec1D1fl@BE8hNs3Vw89pBq4NRU5GNMmiyxNbOz5J5W3i4xcKxVw7U20oaKkR18DH0nlrm2l8gwzy12gb3EenrKICIhXoZSb3hToJ@W0Y3lzJyOLCvt0LyAlYvMLevlfoG5NXupufUf4GR6QD3nWVsPeoHdeFappTf53r8A)

Beatnik code is on the second line:

```
k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz
```

It pushes the needed ascii code with `k` and then prints it with `kf`, `bfz` terminates the program.

Every span of adjacent Latin letters is considered a word in Beatnik. `Dv` on the first line was causing problems, so I split it.

`(` is moved before `coding` to hide `8` from Prelude, just realigning parens wasn't enough this time.

Refactoring: moved Delimit.

Comment: Could you please put the whole code in your post, add the local languages and insert the VIP score?

Answer (score 3):

## 201. Julia 0.6, 9686 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyNNlhj4LHr/wb6EkvqKpHhNUqR4EVlF3UqqUkkqXUpVJeljJckkmVIyMyszKZGl0oee8aLX7fGDPZ4djD1rd894FzsPBnaw2Ic1PMAC61dj4N/wzdNisED/g95zTkQmkxepqr7u9noBUyIzLidORJw4ceLEiUs2Faf3m9@E8cMOTX3U1U2Xuarjsrat3ah2iq2P2DNFc/LZXCiEUHW7O@irhuuUQ2EmM6YZLa0Nfuaa16qhfVJtCM8yZtlm11b6zO0pLlOdlmKpDjMHrjVwmdmZnyzH2FbfvNKSmLKvGV0Ac1XbslWX4lcYOzV0pd9sK1Mx@akMLRviHbap6p/7n13WMvt9xWg7AFlg7JVpOyrCt1THMTH5KmPDLbU1hbQIoIqtmXv1/edTUSXGnkMRFUtXh0xpOq6ttFzNNJAmGXa8f3p8OJVCltmbk@3t6dAse5k0DbY9aF1PR@XYqe0oujKNf4XVB665606H51m9qxoKy6ZKqex0ZIGt28pMklVmq0q7o@lqChqEJVlP1S3VZhjCOqbNdqFIejFTzDTq45SpFqYtjiOn0ZaYnsu5U/XJZoDwpt1TDShhZjpS9iOnIrJ@RFujDBR7xKJOz7SBj2w2cNQ2uzXtNjCXoY9iCUjPhp9YU3HUwgoiyPkIrg3z1gAmck1o2ubIVZlhGklKjIArTN5rTDNWNo@h9YPd6fACy@5Nh60Co7WuO7NtmS2yI9MaTYeW2Cttbx475zK8I2yYbWiNqTiZHSoQRNlMEj6XnewFLWhd6MzsyoGCtVXmGJplqS6PBF5RbYqG1EzXjGvewQ9tsz1oYedzeyrkjR0W@cEJtSBVjVlCTKTQwcLEQRwMSnBs9tVgeR1mqNBAjqW2tI7W4oylDl3VcKDIToppUIlbTddZW9UhwRh7K8EcE5t3HNTUlV6qlQohY2IurH@tM421LIvxKKgFFGk7U2QqUo99gni957Ch1WeO1odot2V2OqrKPqlWD5KH2maIwadlTVXL9y2pAGOoHmlUCwQCksZESgOdPArd2gqQ1nYEDVytD4TV3IjDVMXRUKBCEkc12kRVyxe1JlMmWJ7daNDhoeoDm3A7qk1djvBC97RVQKn4zRy9tTXXpV7D6uxQVWx2YqtqbFLsTmQJmZmYg4sVSVGjrq1Ftg62I9C4PEVKsaAx7dzJ6xchhaWqbKlRgW9Vkiqhrf1Ndrd0gW4uZYEBLDuqxFj1B@akLy5U@A7lZrpr34cAawioorO0ablpJWlBAZMuFDCtoBNdyZtsytIDGbO1qbYIsByHakNrgPBhbxJUs9bAtnEkGRNVuYZK66bRBXpCZe2BgfQwWCEDTdAyYSBIMPUGqAaSl9oI5AJS@KSnQaM52CSBjsXHQyIojIjAxoKiXr6OqQ8IDlI6LvIyUAWSIsbdDnvDOoqmYxKIR1S81LbqDHQX0wyMNrY8jHdqO8W8YlCHtYGPbyA7BZBSALB@P9AvqVAADA1hUlUx6sd/@uftbhfw1FstkG2CXd@wttmikVuhwsJwyJBhQaDqVCyAS2DuPDlkcKPoWpsEhGKMRBZUCMr11hzobWZChvatBr20p9xAz4bO1XJVzuR8sE@wvnLNpYnGORcq3lea0LCUAeVN1U6yZxvQSi01FCaeSfYHbqfIktYWizjp76NPy9GnixcqFC6Wii0vpdPdCjBcapmCwBd5jHPe1CckpeMqjqm1Q9bI7ZlGliVbTGpVTUs1opEJHJFExG5GYimUctFYRau2Uh3NaEcja8CLNcg4Equ0qq1zrXxZmUoezBLQ3CIa7K5qtBWTQiByqFPcpPsgzVMwOLxJClcgznQaSHKMTgWCkTDTYTc8IEzKDvKliQwCcijl6KpqRTMpOYZiAuHm1hsj5tV0CoeocFm7jEfCkXiw6oQBajpRUeysJ5qJYku3ejhoAVEMx4KRwEbebcFIjZLR0VzQOBOsSXxNowhIFpKJt2rEVnFI9/mIuiTvcpg@iYJSYBh3ocmerLYDHRmEAPRl15mRxrp5CxlSmXCYAdFhYKZKF5oGEvOK1HlFeE4UMlklrmgAtqbKismmBp0AuxvIdMHzgboBeC7LYQAb7yQB2dNXRoClxYfVcYdhWgf6Uh/EA2hDLRVlDggflQ8omMmA@p8DOjZq25lkNp@f7GMzXcy10/XkexDSn9KP9iSsfLAzoaBhHfWW6YrRHShdlWtiTGm1VMsVggpq4rggiqbHGwpMisEz5fRCS8@m86ZBxFMtxnmgkOetJ4ZCBaWLUPSToM6oTBFTFdAcbRBL@mg6dwC4mcpc@oAgEwX4ID1QBE8DACZTh2pr4IJUAwa@7WmtHvAsls7gcpEPQtPZQ1Awd5DsyY6fNRZGrj3JhlJpPwiL8SCKJLboLB4YXBFVbSKAGj8Y8DhmxenPQWz6RYSBIBCaSisp4L0v4OybhjkHKRDSR4sgkzG8HUATO0aFEgYuT@2izuprmX4TQZvhRKCN/NdzXcspwzihub1BMwWckj6xR7vugYHMknbtkeaa3N3UzSaIZQf6Z9rLId0aNLXhVIUozG/DKyd0AwpYx2FVGLk/DoDropGOAwKTwjcQOBAlkeAmFPxXAkACSgGhoh2HRPE2CJXjkdGKSinqSinodFKCSdhxJZjuSJjKp8uG2UcpxM5IMUBND6Z9moFzBSHzSeQrc4c6X/aTXheJpK5MzYjeRRYXFyPlSA0k@@LiU3CtoespuuLgekquJLkQLoUuSpEgF8aeUwoMu4zcn3uYh7FLbLYhjkqfNCuqnJfLucuEci6LZxafMRB1INkAOokPwBOJVavojMWk2i1UNNXsTNZ@A6XzccvWLEGEF8qNwv2CCjkig9a3cBppqxUcZB@nSb9qwygISmurF7UjF@eZi8uLu4t2/OI@ksDUsYpSbUKlIL9oP9W1zQEMl7HzlXJSvozFznMwSDarkUxkORotJnXISInFvivG4gqndjSigtSOXlxEgKiCPuetnk34holsLOaTCsqBAzPohNFI6q4I@Tdjl7F4BNLGIgmYYlQjEaBMC4ngUKWRMycIdHD0khNmIx4PERua9jV@Z8Q@hKVggsWTbwP/bhxPTnv71yBdWcvRURVJ2lwbAW96mQe26eFrXGW2SxqrAcMt1ABG27Y/M8LZuDEg/ZmUWzOYEU0HEYLCcOxBuapNwCDijjaECQL0@5GnCOH4jbrQBkw4TV1NnZFqIjHoODjtVVNztaFDPqykWs6YB0DvAaelKy3o2JPoLiR2AQiBz9Pp@TGxygziaVWJZjVfqiMMLC3FQPq1NdLaB5rTQ/KCZoVTCbsDVEWVHXQDlai2y1ow5neB0upQc7kOD3x0jEl2FCcaQ62xzrUuVPZQY8BCeTYAGs7NFsx3VNAcMJZPHtmWcaPZpoFETm0BamD4CrbBFPJ55AU2qtd3s5sP03cecqDYTLAcoG0Q6zRxW06LpQ1TN7smWwYAZM1UijP2roGmEtD5XJheMkf7RASqd01jNMWDKg73DuqIciHna98KQqYJPnUFsobNr/QY4IE6H@@@34IRQs5nMlB@z5ehj1/JAJbpOmJgi40BhMlWR77BlnyvWr3RhEEJ@YPPIoGfTJV3TD6vV2BAhVKJHv6JkgY7OQ@Bfu5FtT3XvLpvkYaEpozgLGOi9qAMQj8V1eHdBmoYngrGUI8UE0hnGnzcvtsgO096AzWktnomky5Aw8jWWLqt3qRR4Egg6HqgKichK9UmZcxPJkzIIdccgFbXVnWtr7m7ZO7SDVRdxsOyF4tWuzGCQ011Q2K@MRavaJIay1qjy@G3hjggOSGVnmz/YHOrcVg/2alK6YFjp3WtCRzcVht9UDx11ZHY9CfMjlRAJtJ/utaPTNOt8ua61tkXP2FM4yXf22zs7a4f1Y/e8UIQGkfrD3QFi1JemgLA5McU7fWqgB2wY5t9XyN3REMs5ZD06oTNH6enInYFYwfC4h8IL2B4H634qVao22qxpMm9fqAAXEVAtOzTGNaNxxGSLP1@oIAsEkq09qfsphdYwkDfzj9hAR@jmxf/cCKB@U7O3CNyxxg4VqBmd7JM4Tdup4Ojth@cpeDrJLK6Pg7OUTBfJ5i00AuyzETNBfbxrRA@vr4wF99M1FxgH1@e48N1ifnopmLmgfrICoQM1zHm4pqKmAPoY1olTMG1j3FckeIeWvgQec2NfjCRj7tEuHFxZIyKlkpEkAeY5dzR5wsXTgNtpGMeycoTsRjFlztYsg2TkzUEQX75jAshEARanGO1U@7QHaPIBVEkQefgyyB@PGcEWW8oDeiV49J6IYEoltRBgMmFceK8n9icSmpq42AfnLdrVm@ACBgEurQXEozyE/Em9NZbgp0iy1vQNq1RoC/fZTnx@5oQJ4HelePkJjmE2pE9EcmpbXlrLhNxvFvydZbGFTfWNcQyC7YLF4QnMPTumaAw7WkOrX4GJWPIV@wvQpI3O5lQw6VxTHZsJWTJm/nmTSmIiGQ2iNVrEyfFY1cjk5LziMVH0b/WZ1N2QLeknwnQmULNxvCxot/s0M8cgLKwnMGwiEtBSJUXaP1H454Jmr56S2BkAyBkQC3NUNJH9EBrwLzyTNo1JgrTVDsDUILTMElD9xfAkqUiQXaaTe0hUKALFt17zq3k0QAmItnUSkr2Zj1oR4SZDzdKnOweECD0396MMYxNNIU7sF1IJZ7/8WdtaJLZBuspI5oK@I4GUJK4pfNg@4mk6KGf@W1NMFcDXVOIMOT6EsqWgusPiu475qNGnYYlkz3F7qPGLZob2BV/oL89wnm85LaqD9qq95yfCZF40uTGUxtan2oET5wy0gT5geRTBkOeniZduqm0CQufGmkqJbKx9Xm7qEM@SQjo3iCdvqKcnl2PjRfS3N7AHfBfXDv7UrtqFn7nU6U8yWSZvNKU1bTpKE1NfYQPbOV60DaT1nWXKo1FK8yBHde/iWaoZEdXrrmzgc75BOBVtLVuV7W950Ngtz3Q9mmakr6lxyOs4ulajLRn5TGcts5/HwLxdq/4jofppOn08y0MSSzSgl6DpMUF8mSATNoUYXWlOcLpWu/bOQszJCUWBE@1FY9ncjjq@qsh46V4y3o4PQ7VlL5Ump@aL81zksybxKT5knySm6qozmKR/gu9HsYyra/oyWw74HxQrHtm0LFrDijN3ZMtXXGAmVzRHOoNNB/9PMbgODy1kK3GrkfYe1wcb1HsofUV0UtFT26ZuuZgd9YfEqPTJulxnrg5gn7GSdE3S9g26cVOL@m75ksCs@Xi4sYDjPYVko2vK@DKTYBzUuZDRGuZt/h9UNvomTcq/50/2n2aW6qvkFFJnVhCa80VoO3WlzgVF8jpZz4dr@eWy23pc8OFGX9ybvC1vOxouunAJB1/HyMFqNuOw3/nc3GQappiJMnaHHTPTyYKZbGUsK490JaK3jX1QrGbVuDnwQYf2B2U/OL5tRLPl1iy/GWJ5SlGpiGL54Oi/jptX3@JE8gkbePSVcD5yDg7T2yJJY@HKwgTClyPnl@57UyRUqbS3GLyUAPYrd6tMvKeP2E0eYi63mhijUjRBr0PE5SK4HBtrnz/lNxWHs@t/XUiaQbt6pcqEWjca12FwYt@Z5qUZTPyN6aQM5mvF1AdfaAO1Lny6aB5peKOxEemH19fqIyoxpKwLaaBeGhZ9KE@iWnkV5Uax230PSpgFF2DTv5F7WauvLNAF7dw5n0IjkN0zCbsGgNronEnpm/G0eOU61lezzbbE4XEmG@VSMUv61AT6rqj0vch1X6rb8Jk2eyD2mB8RfsLpGQG4b8TiClkrGhMWEvmZu@vb4MuC6oHtKh27STRUP51Qif70AyfgEslmLEZqjvC34coPU@INk1T/5aWAVna1mjnsZ7EvaZfaqEZNUdsdWBjW4aDdpFm5yErBh9nxOQSqIcTafeRqXPQNvXIbHDGzv7IaBWwun9pfgkjNZmJHLvluR9iSLKGyKliavVRduRaqNlUdYU/hoWVx/CVUrlH8flah1BvaZUGV3b4Ws54MSw8JXqsERBLa8PcpKf2VfI@otQr7auB4z0eBBqa@J0TnUrTysQD6SwN@rqBvxPrRgFtyDUNmE25it1VcTqi44KmCH1IvnoLHnOJu9tXuio/mPCY6BhbJXAPHJ/EjZ3z7RNlvi2lBcn4qv3jrAAd51odOd5zLsJXoxa056D/ZTPbVB9voTn0i506lZ67zvMFdc/omT2jp/Zs6hy@76HuARzp8iMlj1UCyt9TnGvc9EfyaDyb6zlB6uqmrn8NdVEeculomvMttVu4Yb8NSb8J70hpQoR4fNGEB0M2EYnG7of6Tk8dwMjkmK5pqUnyPQSqo7GH/843Pu8eRBx2pql2m@9YQMuf4mpNXWW3GhThygkuk883JDV1U8F9pY8o70AZ7/k1pqmWaX/R7tFVTNey6NGw9IFDP2TiTXbm2y7LbJtK@jXMoLl8swhnWbVrNls97UtFaqqKa2jXac@Gw72PzkuFMKaaayy5icEpXQNa2aMUMkE1GH@Mj92Hxr/Ams7c2m8MbHv0ZcEwuQXAN7XyJQN0PJS/WK2dE01DPu6G8nb9PLJuIRZ3H@QmUqBRWU6qGdBK5ActQBMbv4T0olXGB5SeqXpTYQILa99iuhS7A8iIpwV2OED4POPFQ4JwR8g3mBVGdwZdJ/Zlxu21QafCn7kI6108Y8WXlhzdvA0YmqHrK4Z4zB2V/WXIx9ZE8o8uiqTSYvEzqQ4etG7pmuXwX5bsZOdimV3Nn4UazZ/piuZpqx2@TIGuL2l2fdPG3e@gQiRbtuq00OKN0pdLRS5yDLMLUjipszGwBzu3CrMbCObpJpMjXPLtvtpVcDfcnoYb43RndtADzNN7Cb4G8euB4mivB6arzsU5vafga1C@Urpaa2eiFTyEHnXF1in@mOgEGDTbELc9zaFNyJ5jfsfhbEbL87OR00Z1/zDc44aQgF4k9oKy5C7z9oz6DjTrY7wyN69JrVOszD8o6DSXDKbiObee8/dfPGZFuB30rYEjHvNz7@ORgqDluH9N4c6tBlIw@RGELuspujvfuhwwnoI@JUbCsfMhLfu9pptd9r6YYaB@gYBDpfsBxlqHcflQcaEHGHOYlfL/ynVLtE0kuVLjfARGUHMsqRma@7gdxnUVmAd5T6wQV7XwyEx6D39Tz74VQ/JkPlX2HpX4MKSPWjrMbL4EdfjuCxDqxpeHli8su8BQaRoDN4nHDB8bIgqPDRF8o8gRnVT0z7Q4CbEVE8I0Wxyoc1LeqdUwbVulEy7eiQcWxnM3AxyEXdNOMYKLRpV4PBYL8US4kNE1AMyDonODeKaIH0l0GNTVJVitw87P2dLdsJwpy/esyqSyxC4vOVb80AmXraFFh/6OePLzJeWyuhRJJiNLkQujzDIRH1zVoTvPBVcmYDsaPXh5xyRghsI3J6Pbq3GFn5lyenQeEVTXNqjApwZZplCd5id/@LGyE9w68R/@qi2OacI82QHdEYZUIAieUjb7as@8fcrzFbnXLUvBY56IA6Svzg8dJTfqDMQC6Mr8dKZ5y063T4rizJc4Eg2eQ65L@aXgjYvWGtyx7fLG46Xxd9@KjP1UXqWACQd9A2YnbbfnpNixRpuxB/Z4VyW4EMxwbZyitRNsl7VVXKCmPfZkldBN85oOy2BJ/sNf8ZNutNNe7ID2sqcTroEccUO9TMfLWi1zAKX2kHxSbVOARJHIIIsHaO9j2D0pPIb7z@kIHnBk0juARtnwU2gb9WOW3GIRPO2N51oqWie6VD96/uY8c1n9gfXT6n/8WTp2JwgnfZcsFRwpwTyQyj0yVjA6D9Hj2AiTloYSz9A/hqCJYwi3vD2ARApnMjyJ4PGYaVqi19AhYjoz63OjuMwiim5qZ@8kWp/OHxPDqrd0Eo22/xo4RuHBXsOBDgbeGKHmva66FB1ws1Ty2GV5yBBP8yng4ieWaWM@nqrCJEtD9pn1kMmSLdwsDj5OSB0P8vWr694eplxwp1l6U20OaDPFTTaVzVWpOkuN6lqNXLbaNvFA7fn3F8NsJnkxXN26TDseUS8uht9lsm@B6ibMmJeepLHnbe1v3i2lapnPnx1lxCTpPlLhO@NATCzdHe4ebh2f1E9Oj6EV7j3xs23afWUsa5CLaPt3z9TpqDLQxdZU5xvkj@8D8GiULSlsDS/hiMVCwZ3NBCpoLSWlJe4MiKaJ1F9IPi@9owbiZwGETOtozOOoXRhwsA2B2ZBqWPmBhQeumUgrDo0Sl2ko47ED@YTB/YdzZCmRSmJVIFYSiPWVpGIPV/YpD/sain0Ry@NkezoXBCnm53fux/MqziXB/e@k3hYMlL99vTmWx@tNMI/UG0D9UC/Ndn137/RoazIZ8Bg9SepWS3mxpZ8LZ@xp3KLlnZKl008iIZr0qhKTKAH3isGMblhpqu6tCtUSwrHV54mJQ6n8UmjMmECZKl5Tc1nhtIhGqQSog1SwWlMnDjraMFBEb4wOoLvjVfSFwLbko/YKnpIE5jBdGZLCj1cNxCrI5XW9QxLiQl5HnKD6k/B6HFYNx2iYLVCqB4Yqf9RxGPwHRiXPlb1kQyaGM/mSJVkWvroKM@WeDxur8DGKLXFCSEu87JJfXryuAsrUvlJoZk173cShChildcXCs/ECeh9ms2X2cWDSCS5PmPj6xS3O2xR@Mws1bUvB2tDJMMPFc@7euEX4drePq6idcdWM5HuQ5wYGDlQAFLgnZWsIUzJgtg7Jen7jAie5KQ73e0MlmVodcZjX1xIcdqM5ZIrFRuigjqODpMTaiIrjJUV0do/VdQd0kjYM3/xKH1JOUrRDm2/TThpMCgNPpnyVMcGkEMI61dnD3jCU3rZgWP3AEy8RHGF2Ajgja4vJJFCuqxnepTpltBiTKa3MXHuA@xpqkZkkXhHK5Er23L4eAJxz7cWFmv7xn/45v@riwgX3L4R7mFkH3x8JXwfc/8SLkWXw/TPflwXfH3Pf92lsstnz/SJ7YdJ9cDs78OUzaaZOKBO8m4WoLn5rY0u/2T1kDpm1sS37yjDQTChhkOc0A@il9YEpbqiNEZznMG7CMZ7o@RtgEeAr4A9Ub1CjofxU@zKKp7zL6TQWHOfeKdoDrQ65TZsOfX8c4GUnoISlC/nCipyGQiZvPIR08rKLm245wlisDDIxdKNZ1Q/NFh6uYJLTUnS1Wqhw3kgvKd/npA9@QZcANsQnCucM0uB5DD8FxNVEsuiSEpdjmBQHsogcQZnWNjmrgTYYJQeAxDDY8I6ugbppClIBHxvq0CWNaeRNgJp4qRXa4lR@5Y2HKAmIOG68kmO6O4630eI5hEAHTQWbQTpDsGMEK0vzmPX8e3bhXhiX4moWBoz3qzmsa4D7H8@5r4VzFp5Fnb0oJDp9zQfWhj07Nkzcbr0NpWXRbDqbS8uFWIBDJYEKyotd/TOghM4NwqKlalem5dQ3tnZfHBwez1x4QZCRabAIi9TW4hfJVOL80ndE/HJPEnV9O338an3bI2WwVOMdCQgx3pYwXcx5uU2X9IHcz/j@5dm8KWImIznztYhpDTC5Tbt2ZrGPY9MBwA2@fXIm12js7v78cq12YYRnsv887xKgcGoZmQtcFw5dARSZLiYWcdfblX2Clws6Ke@8TlYaX3HlnzLi/nHww1dW@FcVju@t8PZ/h@hEqX@gNJR6YGc41D2V5lnRpQ28YF55QdZ4RZWxqOMMW6GZXSXB0jBRl9lbFcWRKZ9IB9yG5N2J53BIh4QztzLR5TE@zXy4Ew8jdv3xTRLiCoUelE7XmqFbcdrXO3Dmn/RNOZauudFYyBAQ00fPZiGdRy9k8MGU6vmQ@WeoHNQZhymySUbpvqPbyxC/z4J5107E6eaKwwHQ7dC02NiKtql6riPQqdjmALJo4YTsxaAPcB16HKk4WqigZSUhMdAz4hXlHO9qEJRI9dv56DCW6qnDttaFEScaS4Bo@k6Wx3deKHhpA@hVzXk1QLOU1VOgDtg0uTW8MmIYWyuRd1xBbrlkt/ODjcsQIMOkzViZWy4ip4Z3PRE2fJlFEj5lmrFEJMX4TErcPEQr42SISrGNHu4jJNNHp6ORyhY8Sc4H845m91NYKxhmOAs9x13EQa75putHApRRzpWUZrTVYRRPepcvkU4QHrk9u4nEpBkWpztQxI0X7enLUDxZqLhCKI0vEpmSd6WSL@cmRUOplOo5ITyNB5MSyPHYtffACSpCtNNXLBYd0G0yDksx8kYvokbCce0YS9ZwuL5lBovHyaYBD4qAOQuCdsil0bH9KF6@Fk1XoZEw1DHa@PikWexcTqUuwU2ZxNgS2jM3QJtCS2AsBHNUSFImtKBfwF8ZS8SvykyJKzOXKNsQXegAUHOjSU51eyRfgBZUa1Z7Mj49HxAwnKqlUlm0xqS0LzHgi7U5AhHQzpHi3hwB6CtOTwHVUEYD1IattjWQl89eqoahAoGAZ/p4M6gyACazYwnv0trE@FI5yiHMi7gjjmNBQScvm9uK3OkmqGtL6QqZxir3oNZ8uEC9piM0m1H6v02n0pW76JJeHaVB14zVoku9qhzPLcfjS8ZydMlAbevJE7So3S@BMtdIwQR1CEDJJT1WAX4G5a@6ZFSWlLXoUruaXaYU4IUp8h0k@MFJp@6WlPv00hNQlhIQYnOhE11y6B6YTCol30P5sIcspRPAM3d4oQldRYvZL2nxOJYhtdTAAvyQvjiO07B5cZwm411FzAXS3b7oblOqmN8SM1focgKK4LI/YOVxwBJb6xoe8Piqudy8uAfUP57xS9yAzGjfhOoEJ1/SZMzXCxYhp1HmCiET5RfxAAGHUSAiehNKLAbC5De/CcsFxqSnhVzUjD/NZyrxSF6GaTrMr8PPQA9PL0u2dHexmbxhajJy3lHyqY@Xh9eHh29jF1FWYpHwxoEkr0jfs1KWfd1nlWUf@LDf5hMOL6dD4fSy/GQ1nf7w4QPMOOBzXkvVQHzwT@w8Gbk8j64yVltdXU4UisuJZ5FGoGCxaDYbO2ZpdqFpmuW02/A1e3RvdDTMP0@fUl4w/Yd/xsNE/sLheRBEhIa/FU7Jh9nFqqIsx1eyz4wKFK2EnxyTwYm/RfjKLJ9nW/j52//9b//sb/@E/v6Mvv9eYdfsE3yuOwz/yf2pHXAr6G52PuE9OTC1qJJcsCKRfC5y/H2E/Wf7LDK59nT1P/3JwcewG65l02c2PN3wx3ChGOZOcIAv5/luwrXwGoIV7sOjdLVaBefqf/pfIX3tBeDBmNEa/NTyHq7CKFxLVinJ53CtAA45m4V8/@@f/SwUrg3Dn8KyLIdH9NcIZ2T8FJ/ITxgDR1paLUqm@cwr7zDw8cLSspy9GLdnoLmxaf3gHuQD7crM8CQouX2uYoIbyPEtcHgzcmHx2YdNxlQYavFTLj@bIfjelP8olYRPSnSDIXqSQ68K4WI10eDZ@7waDjimKuz/MlF33/@NcKGwd71n8lzpXE5Q/SIsF1cOng2/@sPGhfaIGB7Tzs@cTYd5VPc9zOv07FvgQuEfqtUjF/9eNfHv8Bj/2PCnfAD1U/gswh/9w8f34u8ihYhgApn9LP4W3TUUPg@fX16@7tGfjX87Bv41P@Lf3if8e@3i30kL/45e49/Je/xjM5UJhdfW1sLx@BGohoJnv@ZzCt9UqiF8Hu8iut/ph60cFA6ehVg4eRlP3t@fp74fxisV8Q9KU8X34Ye7oFiX98nk2ve1ePycindeE@VcS17WoKy8yPTz/Rogjq@dr62lGrVaLXn5fe18bTKRSPfsWRz76TNIWLs8Pw@F77AtqvizjD8tB3@zkpQmLw4WMDqXwMXISQ8RwOhmf/SHwh/WPkTjT@NPM3rmJiNfy9evzIPx/8HBECK0YebKtDO9TE9ug0RkGfU0M8qMhpm@eSC3wanCX6YPTi3TGWa6GSNjyPJoOIHq4f/@gem@OjABmwkp3WHGRcSZDjy7BwevAF8H8r6CPy2TyQyhkMPMDfxndBTUdGkYPb9vxC5C50z6oMLon5IjqUwkVYhEtMt8wfp4cXefLXyUEpHGxXnkshJOOxcXaa4dsexKha6Mu79vNLb2NxuNNPLR2lL8WTz5DD7VWnxNPJ6Ga5WnF@Ukth/nv1QjnF57elHLJdFdiEMjZSFsLR3/xs8YJTxrixchmPCdneH37PbmlrvIQa6LszM/Fn/SGEQuCoIPgKbnpp9wMNA0f0//7YP/sv5fnbLo@WWMsejd/VqUPjH8i8Xu7u/uxW8tFo0KT3QN/jAA/Jjk7r6GTgK6A9d5NHYZu7/nYfAbja1xhDXMY61GiceA0GHDPNeLSAU0vOpSVCyqXVwMM5lYpQkhvnld@UzrM7EK7VxZauKaGswG5OUYgeRXKpUV4V4tVipF4ZYLhUpl2YfKgEc4AUh1lFYFGb0StmJYBs7@0QwaVehezki0rXbwgvanlgUzO7mU@fzZD2o02prdaGB47vPnC@hJEdy4Ui3lISRT/PwZOmEkBrO@fVMsmZZgDiens2P0PcVRXNeOwrw@cRHBTa7ORSSG8dlMBoExPcuvrRVWarXCCrgLxVisIi3xXS/Rbrwkx@6X0hKvBszHImERJRdXYxR6H8F4Fl5jT2vA4Q5@2N19mKjNVvKxaHOkxvwAuVTiIWylEC3GS@Kvuhhja@naMhN/5@e5@Mry6vKzy8vx@IVionKnVOX76p1SRiPBfaUlbsXE7Y7Kkye5EtClmKlchBqNzfpJvYGvF8AFaJDBDANJ4IRwcdGyI@dk0cmXLs@xJpcXkUi58ow3bDHPwpGKgEtGQHSxYokqHIZpo9bBfc5Dwsq/ZXk5m1tM54ffFbYyoGZ/XsbP@fl5MVuML4NoWy6VLi8vKfTzIqU57w87l3TvUjV5Lhfyl0nUX66GneWwxeTVXHg5ZNFWotUMa@NqrI0WskUIhHZlTVw4d1Rd9y4ivTVtvX2rtVXAfrhX39g6SWTXAGV2u76RyB6frodl9ObHforOof9oq755cAoJDve26sdbz3ffbJ0eQrgDoyQQCz79Q0UdqA31djC4RX9Dpc@G5ihXV4plNSz4DDs//urnP/7qv/vxL/74x7/4@Y9/8We//uWf/Ry@fwXfP@bPP/63pTz@/vqX/@x//vFf/wUE/nv4/jv4/h@//uW/@Bn/kv9v4Pt/BsL@RnwDcPwLpARsf/TrX/7JX/76l//kX8L3X4nvv5z@/vin/xv//7/EHzr/4sc//Rv8EZ6f//GPf/gnP/7hH/z4h7/48Q//ISD/@7/@Ff7/yV///b/7Ff7/L//m7//6f/j7P/qfyPHn3PH//Kt/y3//7g9@/nd/@M//7g9@@cDvzx/9/eVXhP/y9xDy9eX8GjxfU69vDfnlTyrPb0ONcS7EYH/2j3/8F/8IOPdPue@/Bx/8@1G/8D1@TJzmdsn4OPAXjH1Og/aUefbZBwWU/yOGQjD7PImNQjNe6K9/@c//EoMnYP9REENGnoVdQmA/t18A7L/2CxaE/cWPv/rZj3/5D3/81Z//@Ks/QoGWXCkl6omk/AUrEADmvwIOAQtfAweA8houiC@yxVAWHItraLUIyfEPH4Cki@ACLXw5lM@BLyTXyC2jGxLCpGaZT6vjaCyA7zC0UgIf2hHiMILEeVQcotbjrFqtxkPDKsQRKHgxzZDVijhzwolDFfBiIp4m0SiCUsqG64QFUlbjR6yxXB3yhHEMqBEGhgXCoCNJzkrxYnUTMqwONxniQuTx0Ad4fqjWitVhDdH9QEUAHPF1yBKgqli6Ye0H8FcJJ8CHhps/QFGK1Xi8VoSQKlWVcks0KE85T5WjuscZ1RvDGUMz2tNnjH0nyUWJT@CAlExA4298DP2UzBhPIf4iviyqQ/@ek77LmB7aaUj04WE8/ikGU3oBAHiTSdw8Bd9kEkvzDKKHHFWcsoVHnGMAysWFvccPoFE2HopT@8bJA/lDGb7us1YLeBAdVmdpaQlcazUpJx3ATIDZ12XHVWxcWyAdp8ykQknCYNyLoi4d0lxheXMZfmX431qk/aScHMuhpQgO5RHm5ZGM58wVM0yl96pGdVmmkscJLhQeh3P9lBaIQLFcYbFQlG7WjtGEU7UseL5yuuvmEHTIhCQl5EKJ21nFfPSdWS5Xf5BXVkPwJP8AL/UW10tDM@CLnlLYu5CgtbvkGvU0cIK6UQjVamKRi8mh2vHWCSQ4OWByNpNioHjeraxmV/Ir@WyuUMivZuWVQmmlkC/mQEIVMvlsVi6trJSKpdV7KNAz6OeJ8nIzv1b7BzOf/@YfzPvMD8VPqPaWDVPs8PB18j5UGyaT6SwVuSrnVyujKhSEgkI10qS4jj26S4IWis0TuqD9VHe4dQeKFrpLIqsuwIeFFkJsAYLgA5jRxM/EuvPuQUUswOErE/ginCTngRlioQtgBo4tZE19Qth2T0DgPJG5M18YOzPoPMGzQPuQBbSEwfZwr6NrshOT76lbV1uhNXGKpRYK0YLFOdD1MoRXkp9fhtbSfux8TBs9/iKxDdsELfWnw6wrxjWP2tTw6sGW60ftKHjBkNPX3N4DEKdWH0@9qPbvDcNWvwkFRHslB1iHH1s3zXkAq@z08IFavvLPFuLKHx0uBPCj3ec7J4HnyVZ9YydUYOsH@5tTj7wAyrO9re0T37vKY72keR/Fu629vWmveOBMY5HlVxMJEJHwg88EfeiZWvreA5FTD4@dmQRrHPNb9Icd3XTkSKSr9hl0XRnfS9ZlDTWbZ0slGcReAWeAVthZqZRycvwoKsdWM6V8y66uD4quKz1dlGCemV6rFVsK64Lkwc1fkJAOMWhOaAcmJn28vBzPubshW23DJOXWoPMZTXxR0MBiDwbCA4PQaWvdHki8W9MDCDUVhcH3Wz@QXg1@3McDXJ4Hhc3E6HPAcblL67BMKEVGrGypmC@WctliolgqruRh/pZPyNmEvFpcLWUSckYuyoViviQniiul3ArIRojNl1ZDYZAfWiedBtEvSxI9NaOFF4yu4U2tZqpXC4W5DQDGW3wDXljxAwZFJuWKFxlIJ4VwYyvTqosSvmMyg29wBIQKa7Hw9vZGZntbktbRgwa7jYwktdGTL2Yyq@uSpFLMBojvrCSZPA1EAZjLPZnM@oYkDTgCPBIpST30bBVQz5QkDT0b9e1tzOcKPVlMD2DXPIZ7dM@zCmAGenI5UlQl6aOPDuDqPKMVKukWejBPjNnmMRsQJ0nPvfJkMoDhiMNxDDteXet1SdrlnnodY15QxfO8qC/RU6ePJNngAR6UpC44ujbMqCWpCU7kRElqgas1UiCsDy48QWm4iiSNOIGQRJI0JGildS2BUiXCMZudnR2l57bVLv@MbP5sQdEgRhsOtrabz583u92mPapvPT/CmBcvdpSr0cBudpsiWbMBHxPSQMx1fzT9gTLuNhqKPjfmJcQYUzGNUUPFsjWUj1Am8eliJv3GC4h5ATHzVkE4Nvj0AbSJn/U@PNeVJsV4H4qh57DZlCrIo@7IUtFUgl2GNghVgiF9pWWbFXSBFs4WI9FIYnQuXyY@VSiG9RmLxu4ylXsE6UTp9REoH2N3o/NhNXMJmrdcQRtOdLH/VJJLeam8qDyNDtFdkMqge69IsTK@eMPsRFgkKT8dFKXCqlRehqf0VMqBcxjNRDKMwU/sfPXyqbSKSKSnT5MSlAS8AKJAQmm1hAhLq6ADVO6BGi6I2ebAVRuNaPRWVa5jMV4j/rIednZ2FrvjW6I0qqFb6USHiWGVl4ZpsconKPw0prYKQ92g5Zo2x9eF@n96milTJSH7ogS5p9OxNZRGKD/gOTZNo4HZN0qHzvAoAx1j9Pa8kHrrlEMnqAjSi@wYHiNu4rtf6IwqzDD4fQb0phYV1MJSKFQTWtGJOnRTOyruP2klk2cTn7W1M4DDs654fHB/0Gfr7JZywcME3n7qRnUdUGYqBp67V9G7NAwPQ7W24iowP1q/G5TLAva@0q2eI4LP@LOWlM5qZ9IlC@abX81AqU6N1tra@edLUA2BnqOwUpWzxcowTKdFVlcqUZiJxKqO@pEriJ91NOktNqoZriouOYP@eWaxICfuko3kva447pK8mi2fD5bOk/Ll4mLmc3dNel@TLjFz1CDpL2h2BJFfgTCvOfggEe5oHyCelZP81SFysRBL4ab2htlp0OsB2IfAWDBOaFVgoNdV0HbkUrYiQEKW4JuoxKL43h@@uyYaiaxmI5FYpAJQixBM7Be7I26JAA9HngDnwlgErFvKQrytugNQgKBHecX0S8AV54IcCt@H2ppjsZVSKHwXur@7X6t5@sVLNhop8aTnfcJYNw5zqDStpeAqzCK5kqnaM1av1rtH9YoArW/QTCcdYhf8zFYyvfitKzbxtdr3/HmBq3WQTYgThxY102vxWrpWq12EJEkKS565PVrMw/QIbQg/hOkWP7Zx1xkYdLK//ArJpZS5xnR@GfthX9PvirlkjVTvKHS1@3B8LY0rgalamojVOqB18lDYMIUTja8udA3onvm8hHMxlVnHpe9Xvy9@/@r04PRgmz3LlIvlIqcEbVx4lkjIETkClH0GWoF2tBUKW5/NvPyD8aISLluR3EokN6HZXVTFieUo8kH0HNcn4Ht5DvOsyxi4qlX5qbxa1hyxfBAtOwNLtWNP5UK2nIUBNxZ2anieMrsarpFDLqyGL8Mc6cpqDNxk@c7K4VpaBMurMiRLch/weT7sAFMUX334DPNm8aZSLUuudFqUdOl@7R7@a/fnMLW8pxnmPf3jTxp@7jkA/CO47@GP8ScAF4QZx1/@kFzj/2v0s3HACy0VoBXCH6o1aOzvG983wqFwKVKLpyP41m2x60JM2FCxWzboT3WW8e/7ccCy4zjLvg@8a8ssX5MZU5fT6fRF7HUWdMBSqVAshEO/mf2kl2F6ubxQZxF@SQ4XwfT6ee@4TmTilWdoFVheSG4eH2y8hMk3yGDVwFc/so2D/RRG4dsJx@etWrqq2PpIvJ5whFAouk82DvEF5qebh5TmjE7aUShN/kUuS7vtsng7SOKGyakcLgjl05mVtJxncrGcWS1nC0wBMeTgyXrhWsKkjKq1YVojrrlHN2KUeKGOMBi3p8FMylHL7PnhHqWgQ/fLC5tbrw7Ywf7eu5QXysNPdnaP2fHB9slZ/WgL6vFq65hJ9WO2eyyxs92TnYPTE1bff8cg@qi@f7K7dYwI0iEUYahJcIL5ajRbc0ZOGtUMh3TpiWDHbF2r7mS4YltKGu98nAw28JUQKt6bPhk@MGA62g6q6cf1BT5qM0SvtNt2CI/4aS22gDr6wrJq4z5YqZdxVll@8PZTxs4vstbKfmSVtTL7Rm5tlekZ8cf0lX7uiC0uLl4Yki//g9XwZwnBINwcDmHjMu2@31qIFlbYMswNsiuxccz@weFCxvMtnB2dLMh@3NHmQtb37G4v5HzPFvhWfN/22eZC3vet118uFMbJ9jcWVn3f5tbGQtH3AZMulMY49zcX5EzII9aNqbUX6LVX0e3dvS22DECxykQsmmPQMRUMhIgODIfft0DTouXl256ZICWzOZqCbqtfgvbAJ6AWUEs5R7peJtiyacFPX@0DMCQL@XqfYndbCYEV70eBUSV0F1rACi1ghQB@AU/6IhxbrLJsjEH0QoevTUf5fVkJJp06dJ7vO4etobZQA2ZI0IUrdK4TUqjiLXWhhXuBMtohk1WHNqsSKKjSTLKlWAwPg@2f7u3xzGBcsE07KhEkI480B6dpATaoIvxi1SGUNw5vFmoLpNWCUCrwTXqh@4nWDE23JpIC6rmw0AIEk9S9UfQEQ/UrgWueiBc9fJM5AEM0uDPg4qfgotEW1rWrui0qUAyJuXWwzWuIq6ZVNtnKMYaZEqUomm9f//yZeb4Ld9JrT3qNCMctkPNicXy8pFWEjWHYgnf8kCDoqDWlXECOicchNVSH4gL1WgCiw5efzPZKWYOMMhH25AmVYw18pQhlgenilCNLIggiEAQj8iEyv2iLVNzYQnoZNzXw11AjEXEc4VcwNkf@rRIgWacLOtWqfi/0m3PBgHlLZUogi6hOG9sa3LlsA/woHoGTE6wJ3STBvEi5gJE4z0gwNcE6EDwlUxuaAZyr2mOZ6LECdEZq/f1N3kL8ChUK5wFUY5B7ZWowEBZPsPsSoy8sNG2YvVU8KJCHBAV8i0wTRUJwuMfTHW1SsmXeX5AtMfXXpNzdLnt8xFMDOwhOI7LiPIbziqguBdbGQDP4BTLsv1VAz1mSI4vHBYTPZQJsaxIumeRw9x5ffqESW9O1WPzmWqBYfrAWW19Zjd@uFjCsjVkEagEiPgp44wBNP5OtmZ2HAsZCQkG1@WkoYAAd8xL08QkEX5Eehtxx@uS3p4dBujzdlaHfQgtyqcCTTHpbk972pBe7L4QoDKYE2RX2mTXRJRfAhaefWREcbS4rJxN2Jr1khqgy1UvT8SUwzwF4DkUlB0MGnBXGKEFSDl4Xr/TxpSVVVt9u7O5vnUzGIr6U0xAF7@ErvCmP2CSYKBDGO1H0xPwSRTtIBK5vRg95HgmiZ@P45Gir/ioB5YuxtXEPmNYB4Ef0hIka3Hs5QKihtmA8bidY9LjOlmPsCZYswYStAD1fnYVuOiqgejDH9sDKUlYZDuL7J3tSGHtkaE5WUpRFY@zzxQUMqZlVJvetz7l@zljNtdkot4rKLsfj6yBCynsCZp93Ta5sICSwp4L3d8zN7CqTYSt2jrlqDzTuYcaexU/1usexjYZF74ymZdKkzKnQW@BRtogbLWBcnFRtHtciaWxEPsBQ7MYQhsM52bripJ8je1Ksp2DxsrTVby3LlzTaybIkeVnWKNPZMvxGmPtguhSaOodLF4OYlmspeFRVRB5YaEs5xCA7FOI2lsD9UFETXxThxsp0rwfKlEYDLwVsNKKOqnfwVdIDuwVDPqrLjgDDD8ameCR1JHRMRgryoP40GdHW8Ggp3t0Io84UQnqjdZVuo4tSjqGQXzLHVS0qVaAYaCbDV6oGM4QJ9oQfmhWPfAVKHCsLrXhbwf7gITufuNKH4xg4vcScYBDPs6E@m86J89lmThze3DYviXcUeU7c1aA/rwQgGB6IEYcJ58QY5sG8BPxGnHHE5XmAgOdBAl9eRmPzmx761WSLB640Ivqf2ANV3M@zexBgQVAuBQcG2jq8qQLTtjS8fnsakX@cGVJGh7HAyWqfrWJjTlKclqZNo/cwCUR0NJBumGbDcqsHWL@Ts8VYIoAwgBGv3Osr@kM4WQAplHAOkjB/ezrzrJ@OjxpZcBrvOH0KLwYw2jC9GycwrUfgMXYMi43vAS/gnU5@jM/Mc7rcGF15lnEoHK3z2PzyxO1XD0F7lZBjQYL@ttknvzX7ZCB/7JM/KesqO58sx2U84C9DwLiOXgf/SRl5pZ7MLfZNNQ5yjapeP8C@eEtJIBt@O8Fktj4aIYF8nvKqQugx4CuFBOIKIvoG@ULNJ85Oz0s9Hn@Wqywp@2m4xBv3BjKrBwofwnsVGg28kLTRoJvoGg20LDUaEs@BBl4c8IKDruhsPC4FWmrDpNiolFSkhJRM1o83dneTmiEl@I3GVclxTVtt4IVSUgKXHKsSCawGwvRU3apKYieY4jBKLT2cRz2QB1Twy5kQEM@F3ngfvGn0y9m1glUyv6JK5lRm49sPvyK3I8oND3o/lpPNrxHzMtqgm67w6jBb1VDQ8LuaxfuI8UqIiZsI0KQvisDzdcjS5@D9D7xI9GhgmGhrvEiB3vpcZWTtk7ybUaSZi0xEb0dTDyIYcyrnPumQ3ujC6Jastir0LDIPpaTxDYmiYClR0wC/ewoav1hiPKBN3pYiypvwbJMOmjGnijoWLKaFlT@X8DIVaIBD04Jf/0IVcPtXqoAbL1XBIE/UgRtvVMEUHeEQl6uAi65XgSewtzS@zbGvDLX@AA03wSP7QpMbFwuHfKwJjfoUOSn9OEURIqXjtbhRgTcWl8oSVN2hq1ymr3NB@Hk3usQuQ7NClu4fxmIGVId5SOfeERNL/A4aKaCIoWh2RGkgbUJiEldCKK1cvoTJZ4B3PBGD6vNUmMmtnogIapLw04/Hq8CNMNWJ6QVSBCYPvDDjBNzKFHxzGin3sbKvgoxbLAjFFbc55cZdnA8WPIjBU9RioUdmUv@/mScFm@S/0KnS//eTopmpz@95KvPIFOabZyu/w2nBf1Xo/6tC/xMU@t@ZNv@ASj6NcrbHT6nrX1TDv139Ipk3gmHD7t6g6S37U/Sw35EisPpNeoBX6nP5MV3gy@OzhyYbHNZ/4igd@k36pF042zbr9fpJX7aPnte79V796B341zN78bOrlfXN2/Xn6@365mb3RXdjX31drK/sWS/fFt8973z6qIL2vnPw4v0n3Wr1Qm@PrNsz9fA2pxad@mDwcXdn5O6sn/Y3jvPvVm8zW3q@s65@3NSdzVcnb1@ePM8fx28/vjh88amf6TuHnYxS6ud2XhXebIzOjFD@Rjttb@9pB/3j9tZptr@3qb3bjm9k9o5Lr@XM3tbt@9zGbTyfSe9aLw@eH51eNbfe60e7e@/aGx9NpfDx@tbaTbdLnY2rozehg9xreefjwUF3K1t6vpO@3exY7Ux2R7fzV2@PDtdP3@30Xipb/e38aent1eiw0Hv9@sbdj3dXzgqDV85K3Ki/fp19aTy/udk6CjUV88TOqWfma9m6vT00S/1V9eX@Trf/2paN9EH@Tfy4f3K7ubWuf1wd5k7fnb2@XTl@N3j1@sX7g4x2fNzcUgpWs509vjpZCbX6ud34zenWaVF53j573b/Z3cm/20y/6qn79fahfv28u/PePD7c263nnIEh723c6O@e965eXW9u7Orm4bVu1FfSef2k/e7gIHT6QmtuqjtvnRf1q967dH79euVdvG09P7n61Lt@sX58elDMDg9HGXPDOWrudIabR4VsMd3SPx596piv5NPX8cLN1Yus9q7@yQ3lPo3ypT39ndo3XsRb3ffDj3o6firLG@93P717d7xzYzfrxunHN9tHV/artnHgHGSOXrx81dSvi@6V9d44PpZbmefq9at4RgkNT3ccaCP1RMmvnvT3XlvDTfPj0e57p/ApfnN2nVM3r4/e1D8eZZq3hvXWsPe0/kamfaDU35ju1mD4vFW6Ob3e0fc@HjjvQq@25Hx@2@w46503K6W36efxzvXzt@vy8TCzbxx1Vgr2/pvXZ5q21Xt7@umold9@YxX7rtF9/em0vxXf2hv2PqnFTFM/fndthE7zx0eH2VvjpdZ3t3eOXhXcg8zem8P2zkiuv1blW2N1Y5TfHNqF3NnmW/vd9Y5hpd9pHweHGfUm3n5nuSuvtWan9UZr9V@Gjl/0TvcP39zu5gv2876hrR8WM/t7Oxv73fbKy9Huq8HWXvOq/Xz3rfrWOilcZ7fWzwqbb49z7sn1S7fUuunnDovxE73vdk/joReD3mD18Mz@@Gb4fqXeb6q5I/2dOVqV@xsvrOzwTX3r4FP3@tAy9@Xt7Ch9umde65lPJ7efdpxCfRQvDk/dvumeyMO8/DqUu/1kuS@sF6@PD9ZfHLx/oaxo2plydfymncmdFtNaz87tFgrP5a3tTv9jv6TKnzZf5ZRcvxd39q7T7Y326Zuza/2q/7J/1QoVS05rfff9QDG3mlk58269s5VX99b3TmT1tPvyeGVzP3P4tn14@nF40t54Ozh9c6Bltq5elPa6K2@P3pRerr4/cU6UM/PtS3s/NCzmTEculPK3ueNS8aBnH@fOrkru@5dXhXX9rCm/2M321W3NflscFa@tT73b7u2xmml2n29@VI46WyBJTw8zSn5wvT88DuXenPRvVq31@Lvr1su3hqwXz7TV9MnHq9J1r/fydrO1clb/9FHJP79SS8fb6aa@nX8eP9p4fXjV3Tz7VFxpZ9b33ihvh1s9913o9Y62eVU6uz4YjuTX28ejfj1j6Pmb47P8zYm5fny2c1zsvWranebOVQ9kQ390enU7uNlRV3vD2@LL3tUbJbP3trhhOCuHmdALdbffPjp5@bYe72TVkntz8G7fOiueDfOviuZZyTwoai/rnefD1wedrcyqpZ2dDE@3eun1Da1fBJlyqJ/aGwevd96fvbAyoaxRWP@0YeZXP8Zvhu8KZ@nD@N7gXesk2z@z7Z23mr399ubw7cvj@m58tzl6fnitHLzbyh/vb2w4L@LbWkEd7eRunfpGTu@YIae/Ptwf2lYp9/56rwsjgdkutZ@f5M4Mp17v3O4Wj7fq9edOc/eFMhw@76zCGIGfrbM3ZjX0G35bW4hf1MYfCr/XIdR3uk1zCPKSnyoL0UGhEB0UCvGjQbRDmu8@/k16OXQS3GRP7/3kBp5BE5Q11jZReUixXf/2U3z5QYL1TUiuoatlWvREtOIwQBsnfDr8kr0Kz63RW8vUoaWbGr5XBu@4xzmprfLDcaC@pEIHBuuPcL7pqn2@9V/DV8OIy0rpWnz@Bh66LDG00Gox791uKbqK03/T2wdQICyjm6S7V7ssmWx1dKXrgENvk@tD6Ni/Gxxz0DUFjR@YhbzXUORMXmxNRXWVCneCb7TZf850k1@67804FFAmRnSnBRqp6F4LFV8N62g3qj6ityio7VSI7/j8ql2QwTDc2j0ZRhdGTu0NBXVDtac2gFo8obfSml5@hleOPFtOiyVWVIYait3UXHy7aIO/fKHBc/T2vFmTew/pPKlYoOWKEWo2dNVqQpyIGaJvKhVSjLaY47EDV2SPqiGqqN5uw@Vli1DSvivGPQHMy9bDuLV@93eFegJ3W1Mn8JpAqwHQihakZ9bsv3Nok6MPVAnxxfqtt7snDfGqDb7FcOKkzQM7LgNUrng@q8JrECi/KPnstkzcYQDFR7Mjv6kYqnpjcl6WaN8jbo@E1sYZ9ni3Jb09G4uO2CzajXK@csl3EGZo655HcD/NE84JTwKlejIm6ILYUOHzwFem4xs0OchsfRFxx1ZVAqDdnN7JkKnNfr9j3nugZZq6Ylyjq8K3ysJ8wW4FGoteIhCoB5qy/LqI/ZM0R8B6Q1J/G@y4oJLtNwsBiA2xXjOfGtidab89puEt7GeN9jHMw5916brZio6jl70tN7xuMS8nDj@V1QFaEju4s9a0RzwjNM9EKxUAwX06JBNUw9utGqh1dUwNREebegKlAL6teEF4eF0dlzPBHi8tz2qR2IF2AM0vKt8MhFDnfrEueVYPy0KgdyxYmYmkY@J4W4jAmV5mrmkBETqC42AYIx7hu1NnqMJ3evlcxDidzjOX8M@eBj1lvnEXO5SKZk8UITHsxjhDnyqcX2gErfldB7Masx41FO7gxibUiBeZBjN8DGdaPD7RTgHk5xrSTWZxonZ0TiyIIb9GgvSC9gRDe@KgNfhWXNbhO7g4rUNTJFqDjD5/9jsMeH1uPPTOBgJL@O8yRgbnnMn7siBoxfN7ndB3U8yYKL5UvZ/dS0/HGmECbt5a2lDVoyAwG/gKEYtBkNiyZFncQRD@9iUIxsamsgt5tbgYhVTnBJcuXrInLCqvrUVXk1EK@q4Yi/mdUSTPBpIHEoOQrtVYNLsczXmJVzAxoMxNIliZjyDLEawsR2UPQVYgkPOAgasYhOQ7VuRcO4m4GEDs472chMEXkczJfTkbly/X1oq4xzMQOJU4O7/oy7l4FhJz1AvxyRiOlkcEwi8nawTIc9nAOBJAsRLPAQqedXwyYpzrVISfaTDPlcu5g9PvTHnxzml4gw8lx/chqvZ5EeuLnMo3pVsM3JZri0B8J5VFb6Yah3GWXkY2Bx2BuiTk1lPx0FSCv5lMDFpAv8rUqBg4HEEQKAaICB4eLcGuHhvrmt8@2CFwhwx8vM4JJidYEaYhIFFAYhQhMYgQooHWbbT6lg8HQ3Exxnd88wGMMtnHFWc8PwDthGq/lxOJMU4@XOEGfOLNUDSGcPpGIUFjb3cdH2@2jnDH7O7@c2jCBaxHgo1/vWoucox@FTcUg7@tQnM1KALINj6hEXXlTTWZPwZ6@QtsHnIBP42dJ6TaIQTjiYV2SHyhuQ3NFNg4KT0@Ul2iI708yQcoxiowz2C3KlN0JMeIv/S1yN@xRIfeKDWRChx@QlFApBDS7OSovn@8fXD0iih32KjvHe7UETNMMFuK3Wb0FhDsIIah6nxQ9ekZwuEXJDSvk9L0XllBL5EmWP46OU48AGxQTINCp0uE9eVMPwPPg@clIIniQ4NS0Wir1hzcuHfVBxOVceYg5K3ISy2GQlGmeSMhDXizI6EnR2so6YiWpuoYERcYm96KohhcnqQ9fOswy6RXylHPRT2qS/xi83do5bL0Yl3kI2dg4eqw2paC5FdaLdWhw/hj6gNKVe9QJkKyBAgFIfNrP5Yf/GyKP/YKHPReQRp0M77eO1ZzJ5VF0B457X6SjhtQkDgWT0e689RKUotEzvw9vxOqozapMj6UGc/tiud2BblxgcuuphUy7fL8akIRm0cezSPPFdeNPc2Mqyf@VnJquQ50eqeHN9yQLYRLHWowbCa638EcTci6J16TPfF68bgnzlfuHlfKBGEnNTIx4IzHTzFhbreBbNEZ2wadXKHZ18DG9uceQ71FD42U/KCTN8UgeOKUBqjTHpwnPvEM1YOcgZhAGtJpmXOR3SUNKj6@qEDIkl55YgFdg05hCquAZoC0GB9OE3UlVdJ0xEQxEIhiVYzCdtvr5AQ5Hszs9vSBLgTCUH7gcHwqgR/j4xkV0UnvJKwSauSQsc5KEVxXTSYhQYzbNUinAXGLdaDiae78ahRnqyEq5@lkGj8Bg6JOuGUuChD0M8x7INTLvDK33oF6eIfhMHEsULFMRZyg8E70nh6ynJzLBY7/Hpzts0JhfDoYL8piK9nM@MgxXpnFCqXQT7KTje0JnB@x44gGRbZCnsGpO@iCqq5DJ@aPtoZDP5aNT4uH/DGq@MrVMp/BOkIci6HBYX1823lTxbd643qty@ShnAotgFA8Cbwv3hu8AbA7UGzFcFV@xhIFuVjZxQwpIeqwqu3wd8nT29RB4uPLvmFYsFVuAIaQttmiTZKIg9JBSw/6tBspgQrDjWrjNQCaKw76L5DMEezARUONM4EX6AmHmscbnIRCJFCPRiMLJyMNy0g9bnoRriypKyd7GSrlyZ5MQ5r35lUsAJFXsArRmLtDC4LAM8MMzceXxeunvC7pA49F/zzT4Owgwyen3jxcoOFjzOzMX7ucY4wh7moFx6Ch2MREqKhOlzHvDBxJAO8IVMuzQ3AgegwvaXgiXHw2ihTEd7Fr3BbOSEaQFkGjFA0pNnId7tIRF6dR9IL/7mni5yr0vpjYGTASB@b845ECAlk@xiHE2chpCOyfHGIYxAGl4B11OT3efzBEHP55NxTfxCHeLBzdMTEvQAR8XktqFy8/P5M2vxaij1Km/EjadEkpKhboy/PBeJUFGNYuAAaFInnkVcoDOz0cn3vzAKn0ZJB6rPATuX1t4UV2M0ATlPjKovuEuBe2unlIIXHfvFH5IpXYViPUzED7cCUJGlEwAvEs9XthqhA08KQCL10zkILrzF4aT5JQjDj0OytyBJTvWM56x4E9ge6bOcfneudVlHOyV1WvmtSC9P5nXbNoaJysq@gWwbom5dnKrgYq650ynqisSOTVc/Z@BwMcHd285fcv4IAiiZPL0nftBPuujYshIiQ4RnnUmCf/Js86Bzrk99Vxj/Tr55eVDs36Ht5XxdohivYgv2M6xJvxOjm@AJiGABnBTaPiba7nqRYWhDoDSs9EumxMmJ19dvZQdDogr2mrPl6Nupf1MI05hrBU2Q8cDw1Bn1R7AtgD@0xyHgsQ82HxJehB2AAXCck80Uk97sCIeFyMZ9UJa/D4APWDjBjEImRn4Ijyo@lJpsyWYoRxfJicj8NLIob7cf@vBAsyerAgSA5aIxJjnb9mxK9EuP9tV0bHupslNDfQu6ws/HwUipjQ3/IZTw@IWmN9wZ8d8PlAUDcQiranDKJhCxR4mBvzo9EJBrk/CD@@YeQjX@DDo3mQkm4ACSajqyaCAomXMBuYFlmBScxsMal1iKIWb5PJclNDkiHEx86r8cQ6R2TpbBKXAbkzLs/UagIdo0POZI2r8Ms/SJXFm61pnhq8/QMbfhkrj0uW43mWhYeDvd0OhELrW7rKT@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@jml8xboJAqIaoFdP0qL33FS48jB4IFVnRgwOarGjAiLLOGmIxyKwFA4xgW5XAOt3vS4rkH0jZ3D9BqQxnyzcVeDFbREhc9PrinZJkF9pSASMD7ppAx6QqsdNqzjETq@PJXz7Me4bFkNYpy99hExEe9ZZ8c3v6FDt99skZ3gjG6w5PIGat4u@rlCrv3AHEPCGo4uLMkGfF2DqCGaePazHhHCpBe8mZhj6ENFCD3BUhqOGQzHJcC1eAbvC@5tUuoINPR8qW3hgXh1UzFowZ/V7Tf/uPFrCe8NReo4ov05uk7JtRpqcUXYmiVRCwwTZQVBy/BI8QdHJcY4qOcHyhgkhuENZGMpgnfoMoLym2uICxQ50zSkJJgQ9ZF6zufPiXYSHjx8vMQv984kxhV5Yp/IbJqDPp3OBlJ8CQDK4HA90wFaV8J4a@Y0dk8c793wyhBYh0FeYgEBQade@Fo2rjLJJh8X6GcW/SKKC7iQY@Y5f25e7EuDMRXPoepCP1f8mGi/F1bSvD8cMmAHLLnyF4mxrlxIvqlHo7M6@gwMQLRwfA8Uk3MOtAtjPPkHQWi6I4SsU4jBAzaYRsKrjs2kHZR7wYy1hhWYYLUGFXRhsfv/0KFl3cLukAG4csMAJNJBIQZKvOUXYonMoPoG8bjGA@Tusn4gVXGWbaXfiYeW4/w8/RB/PfjS/KIDo1hojGKeftSIEVjtEwk8Len3M9Ul4r3W9R3prxT9Z2hh1/fB@jh13eWnj@pvr7F@C1VBIYYeuAcB6fsT2FGje@a9wK5neIpw8DMeITafDedemDhq2ymUtNLCWZTm5ZlOnhb8/wS8DznFILiA@GQ51OeRxncMEFOc/ORXMxA18OL5p0Q7@K2ifpilNz4vj8@foE@qXPbthijKQAxl8ii73uTU37IICaGkmCQJxL9@mFWXKZydQLUtmvaX1xlgawqfsGponwOxiixX/sY494AjkDVafsilMZLgoSKsXlJBqh3YLrpJBg2P4mgupCPk6mQ6mxuKq8RMbXYXelpQiR2pF0@Sxpr3VJgralB0hnYNaBP@PNY3947jHsMzhuDLL2RuDdKw1Rst0PWtg2@EZsdCusUHnsCFd7t2eag22N4URTqgAjLt5R3TNTuUbsErR5f8jjAu2rK3ra46Lj6vv04zU4tBpN8Oj@PPffVIdtAxb85QlsytwVEA8OE2GG1sODpTgtjk/YCSXof@JIb@rjFYZw9tVmgAJvID1CEV2iJg@yPiJ3mZOwNYknZ10AkxXXVvuWiZq3xKmD1x8ksXIYZJ0QNwLvji5SVBR90fmE5GwdKS6ULFncPWGVeaTNzC0nHUKcL2VTR1Jd5pHDcijhtu4HiYO5Ymk3199B@fq589Rrm/V9gTcjU48oEwakwycXN0aDs4NG8Pl4@jjdrcE6FGTig3DdtnBuOEnMx36I9jnqXcgtzL5oqI1w8JYrTg/nsDW40mpuaVtx6CjQVHR1ARFACUq342hmul@FrwzD1K5qO@on5BNghVQ7vneXFMFu4yuwlnqWEbbZUte2gyqogr1A5o3i8QXRXb5WwrSldnCHCTN0TvV5xyB5Ns8We1uKnMjYOsSi2@nGg2XyyjaVJQVvSvh9ghY2e2romWHxfzhh7UjOSQDbDTZod5nwcKDaaHEybxSNOSMh4PtIciZ0403qUEFCVCWDivOqsEhIARvUTr4KcYivPXoemGk/m0WYdfH1ExBGvhhA2I6Rt0PaDVpMUA3nlG2RgeNbFCV3NITyB6XeCdQY6ymLTSmEcSsLJygZ9qFg2F6v8EsOJagY8E0BcsE7GBjCKbSi2jyFKw7gYibmk@TJ4aQYas3oAOMmh/TlWgL4@0YCUE3SbWN6hQ0Fj@wVEk/08ivzmeDAd3Gthq2IKgWkysQRlMouWhuJZrIZpJIOYOdgsYoBDsNjXtl/1P1P7MVSADJQ9IGDw@DtaGFsKGiup6GL2CT2daomMLKoCcqA/0F3FUM2Bo49@34wQWqC3QQrdGYJG5H0nvJPqOE7D@OwsjS8DYLvpA9ruhnsTcKIOwju7V8YY6USIGmy4vinGWaaLYzBOwntvDC4TRU8wbk/E4eDo7QmYisErE9DSg9sEXDrjleDbBkB00nExw01ROm@DndJyByREeyZursA9pQO0B@EeDxuPiFGToMDGuiBy01Jtnhlw28gcMG98Bn4dX/UJAnJ816YGmYqhj/CjbMZqId/zgQTwIO4AKtxy2FUDaUD8QsEBnGxHUG5veGuqwkaBgxtf3cJ3PWIOlC08EbfGz8CNM/zJufFVOLT5YpaIeypdBq8VgM4WsJLxffbRRTG/j3kT/an9T6Qye7YuD5YzlNjbjysJtKti1iznTWC1Cm20iGpV3KmxhicsoF8C6Ll2uVjFtRa@a4NsZ9iKt8AgqmK3elAlaC8NGca1iU5trU1kgzkcmr39q8wdBuirmCtXoI1Bv4lX0nSIXv4xTVr3QCM5gETHqGOU8/jopUYSTosDP1/gVk@yH7djft/iWdG8BCc/AOjbkXAEFWUi@6UgDPrHO5t86nSiwoumkCySBf3nIhCvKRH30c9EZS@9m@v9KV@2Mo1RfgRjbGw8mzoShgYvN7DF6da0r/nKEZrdSPK7ikZ2b1wL5BuWMZFn0cNFfmccx1cyPOPc@LUm1J9xYOkp7peNvB43uSAUdX6ghx@cGhOYr@FVxpuW/d3IGc5bIMJa3AKVFlG4M4qn5SuXXLD7zOOtuXIbIj8blAke3RK0rga7Am9rYcrk59psvSO0qwneEJCCIxDaKzma34VJ0ssjSWgIiheez3Go8PGqB1YRx52SwZB7nP7zcnrkE7yiGrWM1xs5f1SrnDvGefibhFuBrbrL3vEGvp9sgvz0Wtaq/wKHn0Y3khjcnFphQ7G/i05aDfkOr4Wp@TfjNT5HlXRhYfQt1CFa@NvExzZ5ibhZdAOad/ibAbOcN6ZmeZ5g7PCuP@eoitjkyV93AMM7w5cpiOMb4A0awx035i/Xiw7quP9ve8@23EZy3bPwFa2hdjEg7rxIFMHhUhKpXSaSyJDUrl0QF4vLgBwJBGDMQASWwlaceyqpVDne2LHjSyWxnVTymqTsuCp5yPv6H/wF/gPnXLp7egYzJLW7XldSS5VIoPv06dvp7nO6z6XkB0Q7xklf5N0H6Dtp3TV7/kC6MqODlQv59F74ei8xagVy9XLdtcZdbAq@9EOZ0EBl3jrlZldvOaSayw/@PFIETnqHY8TB6z9naAsqh/pstQJQZLIiX/hlwbq6E0f0Uo26K@/IuAdisSGrlX1QLoywE/TgbbizIanq7ZF7An8OPGxRx88iv6RfvkuZbb5M3N/bfXK0c9A42Hl35@Bwh0qSIr82KB4Py3RT5p@jc@@@xJv1Iw5xMu@NPDjH8cShOEsogR@2B0EgHoK464I4/qIJJZtjN5P65r70KD3vqe@O1rn8ETPzZHxPmsa@hyZCY1RVgv6dswDOz8O2n2PihzOQHFKh1msPPRlwXKgM7pmwmXMO7p@4kloDik1LENKyAY@UQTc4Rw5QShPRN2Y4aXodWM1uSerYKmi8cgj9JWiHCMgAQD5q3U5LFAPbXKsw8C7wnMhGYls5nC3I3g8qYp@r3aZqxTb3C3nIZm/QP8lI7wlGC4hzg0OrgBG219UQk1EQVIF6C@gpEEeae8QdKqN8UK6WKuXPz6VB@Ij9W/JW8ClM8j@lnfe8nX5i/KQks30VA8DgcWYxG7pI2KREC7rkaE1Rg7pYRUuyok9nTp5uTS7RL/@WLchTDMhl61a@GKPxz9ee@9pm1p/Zx8IXb4aTSMARqxxFvokqprPPz2Dn/4rVyOuZi1xlRfGl6USy6YQMqPY6xhPZxSxpHyPnsbvHF/Z41aSvf3yl3S3DGcV4MrVrRRRtdQSbqNJ8GI9GaiJfT4k@okEfUSv/janDp/c1wRYg7G6y2vFr9Nowjoh0tPJamvA6UM8VKu6mtv4s0n5Vr6m2jyrtoynynuFFGq452dyoijTtNq9eiYgaOFu6sI4vkb/UMNfmLcqpvHEZp5TR5dmh7sy4ZEz9nS8FE0rrIG@BjJHF4bWiIeYktZo2iRKuUosoxEs5KqdwzebHL6a2Ho5geFlKTsTMS3zZVnsRxwYDUdHZgLYHufgcRVCGl7FpKKNTo@YirTK50OZsQvQL/P8XaytNgmzg8aWR1W/RyOpLq5EvrUa@tBq5zGpk4WZ57I/KLa9fBtasJ4rnwP1nFmBBbe@J9965dySO3tkRD58@@F3x1b2n4r17TyBlT@w/vf9o94GA/ztPDncEFdA/77ojVLkXMPXbbtul2/mlSmVFEOa5AOUr4rB5Jt4ZtN2XQDwbfvNs65S/lPpusMmldl66o@mAn4OGqMwSSKsJuivityZ144QW1y2g5DN8R1S@PLGN5M3T55slsr2gcOjagJvf9ogHIT0uelbSRhsAP4BUQNPkJ1nSncandWJaOiUhB07/vPYIAlP4@FDce7KNkT63d492954ciod7B/B1/6voZkds76LbmPtPMYsAH@9t7z7cfXCPErgBlZLAuzUyWL@sCSUEp1Fpv@iOMTxYD6VC@S3i1Xshk@kPlFWEL7Ljfui@pwMkhe/u7Oy0Ri7a7Vv3Dt5@F7ka92vCsjDIpeFQXVog3Kqg0QjUJqNo19iZOrKWxSpvSGdTcQuzaxm6A6LPBaGQ5@id2HOF9QCvEfFBmuJmM8OmUENFNwE3olKOYB1BERiy2cIGodyE2uj2QNWGF6td9QWLbknHrChHLigvrT4hxeCMu/02h9FVCUD3rNVN1QYjBsALIZnAAHgHgwlB84W7i5ckYlVCjAMU/CHhNic8Pxs@PEeuEQ1cZcJ9DgSyJtvE80ZTigGOml6f5zFi1sS7A8VIoSI@waOTnF5PXbmSShzw//KNDV9lAdKCXbALK1sJFeGzG1AD7O2nzW7gC9vJ4W0wiCBu32NNrZNeE8Q9uhceocHSS1QjoGrXHPzZVI7qFcNJgTiVCNOaimg7dLltefC71y0HJe/P1Yh6e9RpVJiS8Z@ubMD9uQZ8GjSAqGjuF@hWaBgQY0toBl1JyrY/AIoEkU98FI1qNOiM226kgJR17Ofehx/m5CAXwiKGig@1TmvYYagHfAg5Rx9U5OYChBjSlDzF1yieQzvag/Bt@AyVIUbYwA/U4MraTOFB1Sg1cWSlyM@n1NpqkjHclbUSxbNusN6@htpnFD1/@2yWR88kLRSTtTTnoz9nVGJAz04jdPPSFahYNA2oJRzcIRPuHR8Jv1x/f83Z3L7/rPjRB4XjcvmEt4Vmhx8vWCmRn1lIJIfloXUnSRtQrTSJNOOPW1ha6TPybomrXCEDxuXUA@Z7q1HTeXytOp/ep3hZ0XRKfPXK4VJFsjchEsJIMuHuVhB1VWWByhyLnEQQ7p3QWPSsq1IKhFPv11sY1x5noQYj0sd9hNRrzLBqpF9jeLvGBz3YWTKST@Pp1vhzKha5pCj6sc35KL9v33fym7mygqLFpIfTVlt0QWGu5mSvZji9dF7Nodu@HB3s39dHt3Zp6/h4eC1s25die622FfPpuPhYMnBdH@1Hl6Dlw@1ToYW@F9IR8yE5j01TuibOwq0FRfNX1PjB3NzR2gM0ePZiRFWN1Kht3O@hhzibL8WhaVQgZ6IJGaLDo@2dgwNh7eAt2zqUhX2v2W@TfSlug4j7pvJ0xHbItNmVNNOkwwRp5kmlzNi8NFrtZYs5cfBStgrJgxTkeOjNQkftBclkIq0j@GQhFgINr3lDVCMXbd2F2oP8ukQ8q6MmlAgnzehgJrGbC3z4sJN92mTCcSswb@y/8IaamXEn0lkXXVWPpiYixQjjcdA8wZfv5Pl7j/njdVUPM1ju18bUYVTCb6O/fHEIFQ/xpbgUncFLpkVNKemsEJUuqLEjs7woh/3ZCUrHYp9JXtjY1iVzLJvG/PEtI5Id8adb@M4/lZntM3nfqbZ4StkwJzQXHnp29AgCJhPEYLFlUgUUP57JI4xGQ5@TjmbIzbV2i1pTV62kaGYSdy0d6A3g4Fdvx7eHeFWw215aVfHzqYpPiUhNRtyt@RpUJmC@vbq6fBXueC9U8eJnxc1nSHz/DM6GL5sGSn/qk6oQUO7uk4LKDwngkqFzQArs2GrBxAoCq5NwpkT6ToeR2T5oy/kIbfGgMXtPjwp4XxSvNScmsbYlY@cTycROIHN9MJaw7iivmrnRn11e3X0K6nZFfTdfvz5ebAiE9@GzX3OYzIPBELdKYMRHDfaKCiL5uo9acQGW4OCD2tOvEQNzS8WxrHO8uS1@4UYbaa5xKxi8QL1@FTlTxjaz8BmqdNYcXrzCC65XdGXKeWgTIMt6BbH1nHVUOLLmVmdASgRdHcpyi1sZTYNt/mXDDL65juqDlMcAxgOmowcw@2ZWgNyzjrcKKtRkNs9pwJ/opCInAa0GKHvo9EVOR7sEb9ib6vQyp3dcDDynUzcklvOmjniZ3ZSQ8QiZWUsC012t1502aNh19lucDWyMTnpDNgZky95Ap97kVNSpUkl1WXYcJh1zEkhSOmlBQuHB5AUmLfmu@6JBkyyjzQHCbEH0vd5xSepPvWVL2TEnTTgCnkgo7/Y7GZoUinmqUakjYQtdy0oSqm95xyVSoJQbEMpk4cTyQtrywgImMKQboS@ZqLgYNQB/y0bIpprEizXXt54jhY9cvz12xc4EZXwVG1FRJTkGWRA7T7bF3kNxsLe/E0WNLW4gj0KllMIehWKWDaPuqCVbgAkfjIPTBieqr/Hcc5dzFQr@roH6g5EBxF/juaoCQnGMy1JcvOq8EnU4vId6UuxO7lhOuuqx7kOpPRj3g4tXk1c0vRPg9EpAAm@JWQkvCd6aGxa5EiWHrciB3uIwLCTylQ3lViGshVKolon0zTGQFtexNZ@bSWwZvX/C1MHKpE06DMgJ2yTuBANkedZlfEsYjvZpGHCT3rIdYdvxhuGhVCrNJefFHR240TUj7kYru2Yl@bRK7oaVMIVpPCUf44iGteVEZyBeea9UZeGhgkf/Wlza0aONvpvlNBpHDC27CEzl2MjmVwmjz51M9NPcgpMzKKLxRuXrBi8IDPIe7uYO03gEjOh7DkxvDgqMF9AcHK2CCCAvkzlAKj@PsZHcynDpJRRJbnG4Huebk1JLiC6hSHItYaOjUxGu9dhstAfAnXFAEvzQAEHQOF8TZw7IZq7itMUq4gUlKZI40@A6bf6TS6hDbdMMAfR4rD5Wj9n0RmTNYpfCR0fEbIHsvDEguAeROxU81sz0ajzdPJLEplE8DmE0KgYMOGMn1dVzwZ5EIknnaKnFy4qMtmQ0cOS15NEIW86xAUoklAJajILyqglhARRBiIvDk8UA5ZUYBc0ngxrET/Am1lhbjdWoQfPJoMb6mMNaTMIaBc3HQef2Ndooo2OvGdpF@/LJy6XwsSY6oyp34rbHAZ80ymkFrKEAlofJaEnojnfiBW@JkNGiTyVoDxLtypr0iK3SQMBfvaNZHyqgWG2zCbLaECHuFgYv5SVUzNdRJvsWMuaaeYzAc4hrfB83QOsEYU6DYA9MsiGKyZACjTrFFCtmDg2XmgSiRsZIwhILF/B1htxvfeGCxR2O/G4VrNzM4mbVIrso9EklS/loY0ONRSkYNDyR@FOTjSccg6GI4iiFSZf8RHCMA52KVxyF3qDNl50FxFVTwlod0lEAp4edGA58TZnviyoIaI6vbgc@qMzjwCbkxWWdMnEooWoex@K1cSiBbR5H8frtIHkqqS9vXBsHC4JJOMrXxoEUOD@m1sIFIJjxbyuJ1CLjgWZRMrVZaEVJQ@NsRr614n1RoqpAe0HCEIGfxL4ltUMy5iat9wwx6FrjgULH/HjYHq@kTTiKaeeu8AVzFUvm5tYLC7eUyjewxsqriVt@0IGDoNTt6fWdsPhjInrskkQipHsPFGJK7dMRiEg4myUpfSgGhHBC@xsNVM1qNOhmaP9g7@2De48bT@49RiFqgfcovL5BbRlS16mUljCePd@2NEinyBGoaoHdyNA@bORR@ySaHTpFKHIsllq4MOBmFjNQWJND90WlvnsuHkIWBa2fw4mQJX03A9NjUxv0pm4VX1q5ENI8wVSvpLy2CS0hGKYT2RKCMZIzhrDF5Z/1WUPlWf9ZwIAtUWebTP/YbO8zNFwyCgpRfPkseNcdtVCXpKidlvIsogo@ym7knApVLuQNeojBmMBfl8vivnKKK@3Xmr02urwdd8nx7ZnXa561Os3S8HSY6fqOdE9jZ7s@OrnMoDLV7tHOwWFjH@N07Twgywn8qVHe0e7jnb2nR5hzCFnLMnnn4GDvoEEK6gdP94/QY2gsyTIBJZYQTCZEgJ7svXPvkQHD3y3ZSDYI8UHehD/SlU9BeMPGhH5PycyjwKoQDQrCQ2YqWJTSCiLwztzBWAVvQ/8T6oAvoOUJPspAXSqqMTmksfH6U@aFvk5nBhS1YzQeBgRKGvB2bCRy0RIMc@afYAHyReQD307a9CW@UcY8NOQbDO1YWTSQwWIZad/V9Wl14DI5nPbbtkInHXkWLtw@QOJrU3YcdItr2VkOvUoOSWkoXjhbhpOjTM5Rs8kl5QhKrfSMEcTIvHatZZTBO0CRRQlNQmiZQgX4BbEm8nkvd5ExA0TJLNhVOX7UhTBs6KMwMn7NDWOO2K0p6/lC/Ugg@pO0wNE0wl/3zUcpIjD5PkXGHHW0PNdjRn9VZ/mG2dazY9P7VGjXXULtkQfQ4HuBzY5eyGdfSHfyuUs2oIEZ8RmP5gF6@TYmO0wVMo37QQ0GKhhNBVsQ@oEeLuj5Mf6eSNeubVSgsYHgciasZXEuu6NEIyE/YAAS86xNaz10Y8NmCVpxmCE2TIhqEsT7JsRSEsRLE2I5CeKTjxnE69r5vJq8TbG0usrazJH5TCj@b7p4sahgN5QqdFgY8JnF1WnMSHYYh4TOO2gOap7ZgNxs2e1LWxZF/cm/A24TlyxVpEq44Zc0@xLMv/gDa51v6K4xSn/LPTQ2KGRO5JMXmzDjfeEDSeKqSdKWNI7tp5dgsyw1i8llvxNSxPspRPPJzyIwyWTzLTXvQo@feuG6EZathlYNcQT/MY/AeR0EDS6v1hd5G2UDXsxeWtdYVA9CBAyybIIsxUGSqnx1aZUVE181scqqCVK5TpWf/FzWKc@vBIgfaAjaa@VgJoL@V2ShkWo@FEoC9RkSbWr2w1ffVPCTaBvMYkng@yF2KnJ8ebt/8fV4u8OSifB/mEicVMCkLzXtiQP/j9fFsZyK4wNGUSymjluWIfL5VIhPfhy2g4c3vswuWyS/@OOrS1fSS/9@WDo85jfVwc1cg0IW3wK1elA0k4rWNTaePxgAnZLQGuMY1WvOWHJ4FkuDsWgHqjpbWpxFs5dU9jQxe1lnx5DPmMFSXBL61yPGaIMjDBJrFH4mK19muFTmpmNybTnukMntMrMuDcxhbDSPI01xDKZnMyZwLEaEjHnUMjcnmb1ZhrjgWqLw4zdHzdN@EwO0@oN@SUYA8QblnbPBcw8PqlEZ3VyUnvtp0tBnYa0JAclxDoqv91ChApoqnYqw7jfL7QjYbLfHZ@MevqE5Uq5Cx0jlMrqMI0GwPz7zJU48ce@PvR70wEFOLWQRQcwbQivpFAZW@lrVx6pOqna@ynKZ9cZL5IaOkqht7ZE3DKgyZ14WQJdPxKBCFd6GAatYeDRQvyBE7IrWkf155PVd24DHKK5ewUggvwh5h0vViDLiY2LgKKAGyJPxWQTDhZxx0o1xOKfko8WPXSks4ci5SDdi5GKEEG0d4fliSfqgI9cyiERaEI2iWJYKKzkeJUK0D@R5FoVYKSxVsKIhZpGLIvIMrTXLm11yW0RGrYSDsGlomgXgCEP0clw3K9A7yNDtcqxf/fDjv7dyF@WySqOYOl6/CTIDRSQJseLXo8G@@m6gR/lE2irGcP9DiJtRd9y2d9bECDWBgRqIKwUzTCBivgBCQ6dVgx7sN4MT2/AFoypEwiqX721vi6N3DvbeQ2sovkQgKogVRyJYF1aeh51KRvKlYjCCSEqYh3ksK0Yg1Yh5KN0rBNM9Jvc6XdvQwILR@saf0mjRXf4ANd15XcYQYrbFTn3wnhB1a020eiIUBeM8fONPGPNgyNqzyYgHQ0sSJnwcukD86irSnusXQyTX98vv/QVVJy1KgOfDe5Uzs@o0pp9y6/JClmi2WD1O7VWkGhqEVMRXDtE3f0LIfA7SrTbCzA1zV9RIkrv9g78RhAMfH2D2jJIigid/JaJvMSL9ekAjl4qveCW@bzO@jkevACai1jTaxcdwTpZGaDRkG8nlK4bvl9@TLQZ4L8A3k0vqWIw0N5M4Gf9qziyVldORNr8G/tQZ/r6JVJq5pmHkgyoRz8c/D5ep2U12ncz0fcNYnbGmJXb44/9Moj7SMYfVgx7AGa05VYlrJaXNf/XXGv8kc2NyBcH86off/XHYx0lqzyap/fluuJom872YpLX9RmxL@goeGVZ@kjoVP4tWE1m5E8f4mobgp2njPokO9iRtyQPp60U/uWLZpyH5lkKiF/zkyiWfhuvbClfiYo93K2W5T1KXucKestBj@BdTmgmL8V/MxTi5bOZT13w6WfwdIUeGD41H56alXJYcToVY2w1Rpb/omRf/bsZbY@5@eNUWMi4OcFSADqWmCO0h1GTDXPkX8ZjyM@ZrwtSqdLagemTUUpW1gGjS7PkJVTnO51bXEg4diHsJtWx@ukoys3K577LR/XjYQamD3u/OSPIY0fMfBg9I3hm/TnMJ3DaIK2xtQ@4J6tTkY3rB8efIB9GRzyElaqAH6A6IG/R3Q3e3WOUUkjduxLH0BswS3aDrdBSFUgURKUnkq8eJQgXLqYkL4Z/0DsTSVYulKxws2UfyIxvmXLl5f/PHekfSozSIYo@hzF@N80dyGkjFiN7KyWOH5OnSUTuRb1qQiqaqIyD16P5nc7eIVZfOSxpgaZi/82f6oHN91GXtQH/Q5JU8/mNwTByY1BPQ2D/5IyGwc4vhlpFa85@rifd5h0qrHE@ya9STUs1P/shC0k4eJM6uXS1kSYypMpbYfSKeHu4ciL2nR/tPj/BCxnSMqGXwdEGPxW7el0mAjV4SzMmyNRDzl1icNfKYvLyCl1/KUff/8rvYfUabd6yKZQzTpeW@HylXVeUuGSOaimuPkByfufJ8aQGt47plbx1nTY4QCNC7/QDXq@/CBwnGFxPs8FmebUz@bDJtSt2yYsZzjan/PLtlXMakXybgUYcT4FQFzp9T@ZIyvhjKoCurKb7eOUmveYwfeqFcfhLoF01BkZvN5Avf8/PzUhfDU41HXsn10T2Rj47hysMTYBb6A7rURLfZQHheG2RbdF44br8IPxXbzf7Lpo8KMm9NUCXaufvmlP9m0u6IhydnHIrj094TC0G3vYVpoV0AZIVW@0Whe96pyQw2DNYKJ5yI3M9IfTnz1Sdv2NUQgwDv2XVWq/eiPegRt2u1enCQWWHV3EMFOVVf5fehx4Yx6hJ5Kr2fCmKabVakEPhoQDnwEbgqZV3sTerT40jxiS4e0WbxOSLmpUhZIRjzWY@DwgZMOH8SVqqqrU@ks3htQoavD6gUoiARzVTBRCzCMWfCSvGb@EKFaQg5jaSh5U/bodJqvPkbzKOjCANoYggD7trl@vvP6s@O@757vnicL58U0NERQrekWSONKfns4c84@r2XveHAjyT1XT9gBZeKSmqfSmpgWmHFFzlWMY0baJZWuPHCQUPtQIcycYu@F9ieNFMlbZxTet626lY4xtywumwMjrSnlAxkGj48Gab2JqJjAxGm6y6pSHxJulDWeyP0p6VgizDm6ACmP0UzQgzUEF0qMoapmEVbha9lnADDzj5wY11R@TAV9ViW0c2ZnH@z@Tdfu/ldWBfJrSeC5U0xpjQ2cWHDdeVyYY@Ym44xr9CC8mKzhy7/rJ0@uadRioO52mJZmaZwPdgFGXTWmPy2dDzBL6l9qYWCdU1R9hVTh5clrws1pFrTJHyFp3xFCLI8byAcQSShmCuLTcxiIOnyxkHPYknFzo1GTqiREy7C0JOURh7LYhjI03TbcIxO25pwHgG@Kmv0klgo/OZLjE/FrogWy7rOcM8hKlAWhjChSGft48Ta60ajjU0rhgAJcQ5Bx@02x71gPRPf8KpF/U3vUTyUao/ib5IMeK8AAqMtuMZKZbYmMvligVfpHrm9hE/1jFUtVApV@lfh/1ZBJar/1fnEShSyGk2sFGL/fiOJxziyyWJRtbKCG3Lm1wtiOA1OB/2lzILQZ7agMxv9EfIL6nOf34f9vjccugGFORInbh8ftzHwqzfAGwt0/oVxdeDzC5f8i6wr5IKfYhvP/QYiakhEpeFUWLe2LBj3s@FgFIgPe15LfcYY5bdX1Dd/6qMbKd91iQfygQmSz9yo73s0mu4Ge328lyijx@RgwJ9bvUGrfAaivDsiV44@rHmA8Aal0bhfJndTbr@Dz@JkhtB8AU07heqga50GgDWwW3YOKc930T2l9WzS7VrkvMXtdQ5dZNzw9kjoSCq7HeI7mv6phdvagngCTNg6u1tRPky0ly4acVdk5WNcscfxnEljIGtE@kKNd4xlSZoZFipFy/d6cv1nlegBGkpZOWLL7BydiIMghFeqnLIAK4ZESmAfMUgfM8Z4VoQ9whChLlqWyEbkhZAJ1I7wq6w0TKCK5PnsFYA9xF4pK1rXhmllnrG6ju498a7Mqeb0TuGhnVR1bR1jc1BPcEBxmuTTcHUNc8hBpS8w4hz7pjH7kXdkSwCQJ4QCIQKPPUKPDK3npESKl3VweCD9lVQeXk@00CVaj2K84P1V3z2hKCnivOVxKJiO5xMAliyffOgN5RAVIqTaGp8Aq01rgSKreL4/dlfvrK1QgyiukQLtDNoR0KUyYEbXsmVq3Glw1tO9uBucip770u2x/zduNsV@4UVJdGbL7ROvm2/niHRgKCM9hVGw7xY4bXvn4aN7RzvbBVGsriI4G6hqWNsYXM7OUz4ZcEgywiK8fEut2ytM5LZfyG6VsznZ9C1z2PNmgxUC2LNGKMcN7axDxeTNHCMGkamDe1VBx1vUsd1QVxuXGzZlPMKoBZYaXLXyFxYsJGmsawFJMLI5QplceGjAN9h45oBS9woYAbm7NVAIw1BCRLnWxs1iUa@pdfpUhI21WNxkO3PrAcjhL0T2YNyP7LZZWjtNkYVNDr3l8dZ2M0v7QsmqiVMn@4afrSF3rjmnl/Y4d6FC/PW72AqbB@5ocH@q5s8eK60VGJBcvXqcy8mE7P/8N4h9s9AsoGcHuQvkrz90lEvYEm/qO@xB087ybTAU@7AUuJPgAW2ugRPUdIHWoDMtUUjSzgM4ezv2h2YdQzt3QdrNbcdZzl1AlaMh2qEMYTN0jwBjroZp3UhaKHI8e9ZHt7iLKH995fGjd2DKD9C/lB/U3z9evFUuZLNwxJMGkoORPsT23uN9vEkY5Up0o/BwNDiT4zJq6kpK@LCPlsPU@oKFXSvjKoSd88QNZO/9@9Oj5smT5hlIzE0YgugFTtPU@sEw96jLb46RY0Un18pdnDgEdTpyuzXmhGa@89I@ydUC@HNqVrEKVThLS4Q9gEIOOhCIjbrXh9P6naPHj5zsRlMgVidhVWTzLU0cQChEMDYmkUAbIR0Mp4tUFbDdJhEM/OSz1ma0Lxvl5ma2NpultufRoNlhj1/ZkIA79rggKW7kzE9pbRRSwXToOpjAR9vbO0dWAcqi7IuJFONoSpsWOyN2VB1MbrhT0BE4PUQYx1l5801KwyJj33GWKpUcqofMABv5gAC0vLBGtdmo6XRsPZDNoVeiq3N3wnURc7JUWio3@/45sKPl6u3K3eXKW4MRvht0XL/9pg9biNPEkLJeMH0TDflJnexk0Ou@2fV6@GB1c2Vxbc@7/3tfuXt4e9tut34HeEjruT/AB/zR0GzAqHkutf9gjx21mbqoEX3A2W6Wh80Xg/JKp9Jeq6xV73TcO6vuWmV5rb3qLt9t3b17t91dWWt17t5p3lltt8roNpqKlM5IedBi8sdqu9erNo0xW1uq3O12q9Xbdzqrd7t3lyrLyyuttdVOZWWlu1ZtLi/f7iytte62LufawvZkYINV@y6eHfEd@I105i4zt7fL0rn/BQ';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v e-'[fa5.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 92                                       7 222222222222222222222222                                                             ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S / \iiipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######  a5# \7aa*+42@n; 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλa k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 p''53'S^'                                                                                                          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#0111118&1&  111/"78"oo@        xxxxxxxxxxxx        /112\     ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._      x-----x ########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPSPSPS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]QhQhQhQrQrQrHnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzQtQtQtTcTcTcRQRQRQTZTZTZ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq\{}26q",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}   @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. PPQ-}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{-ss s
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0, _String xflos1''gem 4721en og _e25 $91 <>60or p#s4;931+R(1)7095cr=Bu8tt"?!"&&1/<>8ca g 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
WWWWWwWWWWWWW wWWWWWWWW
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc--WWWWWWWWWWWWWW<<W
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Integer};g=[here|here<-"W>W"] --WWWWWWWWWW570rt Unc<<[|]
>x=1;y#a=128;x#a = 174;(!  )=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]] --}  
 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#fi`le. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201 )#s>say 27#>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}    }<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s<* 5>1  e*///\)Q222999686#
````

In Julia 0.5 `super` was [renamed](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/HISTORY.md#julia-v050-release-notes) to `supertype` (see also [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14337)).
Name `super` is deprecated in Julia 0.5, removed in Julia 0.6. So Julia 0.5 and 0.6 can be separated with `isdefined(:super)`.

Julia 0.4/0.5/0.6 code:

```
print( size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1 ? 17 : isdefined(:super) ? 162 : 201 )
```

Answer (score 3):

## 208. [Pyret](https://www.pyret.org/), 9990 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1bbyPNkhj4LHr/wb6kivqapHgtUqR4EdlN3VrqVktqXVrdLfFjF8kiWVKxil1VlEip9eHMeDHr4/GDPZ4djD1rnzPjXew8GNjBYh9seBYLeF6NgX/DN0@LwQLnH5yNiMwqFi9Sq79zzq4XMCWy8hIZmRkZGRmRt2oodvfXvw7ihx2a@qijmw5zVNthLUu7Vq0EWx@xF4pmZ9OZQAChqlZn0FMNxy4GgkxmTDOaWgv8zDGvVEO7VS0ITzPWt8yOpfSY01UcptpNpa/azBw4/YHDzPb8ZBnGtnrmpRbHlD3N6ACYo1p9S3UofoWxU0NXeo2WMhWTncqwb0G8zTZV/Uvvi8OaZq@nGC0bIHOMvTEtW0X4pmrbJiZfZWy4pTankOYBVLE0c6@6/3IqqsDYSyii0tfVIVMatmMpTUczDaRJih3vnx4fTqWQZfbuZHt7OjTNXsdNg20PmlfTURl2atmKrkzjX2HVgWPuOtPhWVbtqIbC0olCIj0dmWPrljKTZJVZqtJqa7qagAZhcdZV9b5qMQxhbdNiu1AkPZ/Kp@rVccpEE9Pmx5HTaAtMz2ScqfqkU0B40@qqBpQwNR0pe5FTEWkvoqVRBoo1YmG7a1rARxYb2GqL3ZhWC5jL0EeRGKRnw1vWUGw1t4IIMh6CK8O8MYCJHBOatjFyVGaYRpwSI@AKk/fq04yVzmJo9WB3OjzH0nvTYavAaM2r9mxbpvPsyOyPpkML7I22N4@dMyneETbMFrTGVJzMDhUIomwmCZ9JT/aCJrQudGZ2aUPBWiqzDa3fVx0eCbyiWhQNqZmuGVe8gx9aZmvQxM7ndFXIGzss8oMdaEKqCusLMZFABwsSB3EwKMGx2VP95bWZoUID2X21qbW1Jmcsdeiohg1FthNMg0rcaLrOWqoOCcbYmzFmm9i846CGrnQTzUQAGRNzYb0rnWms2e8zHgW1gCJtp/JMReqxW4jXuzYb9nvM1noQ7TTNdltV2a3a70LyQMsMMPg0@1PV8nxLKsAYqksatQ8CAUljIqWBTi6FbiwFSGvZggaO1gPCak7IZqpiayhQIYmtGi2iat8TtSZTJlieXWvQ4aHqA4tw26pFXY7wQve0VECpeM0cvrE0x6Few6rsUFUsdmKpamRS7E5kCZmZmIODFUlQo66thbYOtkPQuDxFQulDY1qZk7evAgpLlNlSvQTfsiSVAlv7m@xu6QLdXMoCA/StsBJh5R@Ynby4UOE7lBvJjnUfAKwBoIrOkmbfSSrxPhQw7kABkwo60RW/Tif6ui9jtjbVFj6W41AtaA0QPuxdjGrWHFgWjiRjoipXUGndNDpAT6isNTCQHgbLpaAJmiYMBDGmXgPVQPJSG4FcQAqfdDVoNBubxNex@HhIBIUREdhYUNTN1zb1AcFBSttBXgaqQFLEuNtm71hb0XRMAvGIipfaUu2B7mCagdHClofxTm0lmFsM6rAW8PE1ZKcAUgoA1u/5@iUVCoChIUyqKkb9@E//rNXpAJ5qswmyTbDrO9YymzRyK1RYGA4ZMiwIVJ2KBXAxzJ0nhwyuFV1rkYBQjJHIggpBud6YA73FTMjQutGgl3aVa@jZ0LmajsqZnA/2MdZTrrg00TjnQsV7SgMaljKgvKnacfZiA1qpqQaCxDPx3sBp51m8v8VCdvL78PNi@PnihQqFiyQiy0vJZKcEDJdYpiDwhR7jnHfVCUlpO4ptaq1Af@R0TSPN4k0mNctmXzXCoQkcoVjIaoQiCZRy4UhJKzcTbc1ohUNrwIsVyDgUKTXLzXOtWCtNJfdnCWhuEA12VzXcjEgBEDnUKa6TPZDmCRgc3sWFyxdn2nUkOUYnfMFImOmwax4QJGUH@dJEBgE5lLB1Ve2HUwk5gmIC4ebWGyPm1XQKh6hwUatFQ8FQ1F91wgA1nagodtYTzUSxpfe7OGgBUQy7DyOBhbzbhJEaJaOtOaBxxliD@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@6zpO3y7COKE53UEjAZySPLFGu86BgcySdKyR5pjc3dDNBohlG/pn0s0h2Rw0tOFUhSjMa8NLO3ANCljbZmUYuT8PgOvCobYNApPCNxDYFyWR4CYU/FcCQAJKAKHCbZtE8TYIleOR0QxLCepKCeh0UoxJ2HElMHckTOXRZcPsoRRiZ6QYoKYHZp9moK0gZD6JfGXuUOfJftLrQqHEpakZ4bvQ4uJiqBiqgGRfXHwOrjV0PUdXFFzPyRUnF8Il0EUpYuTC2HNKgWG10P25i3kYqWGzDXFUutX6YeW8WMzUYsq5LJ5pfEZA1IFkA@g4PgBPKFIuozMSkSo3UNFEoz1Z@w2UzsdNS@sLIrxSrhXuF1TIEBm0Xh/NSEst4SD7OE16ZQtGQVBam92wFbo4T13ULu4uWtGL@1AMU0dKSrkBlYL8wr1ExzIHMFxGzleKcbkWiZxnYJBslEOp0HI4nI/rkJESiXyXj0QVTu1wSAWpHb64CAFRBX3Om12L8A1j6UjEIxWUAwdm0AnDocRdHvJvRGqRaAjSRkIxMDHKoRBQpolEsKnSyJkTBDo4es0JsxGNBogNTesKvzNiH8ISYGDx5NvAvxvHk2Zv7wqkK2vaOqoicYtrI@BNLvPAFj08javIdkljNWC4hRrAaNvyLCO0xo0B6c@k3Jr@jMgcRAgKw7EH5ao2AYOI29oQDATo9yNXEcLxG3WhDTA4TV1NnJFqIjHoOGj2qom52tAhH1YSTXvMA6D3gLOvK03o2JPoLiR2AQiBz5PJ@TGR0gziaVWJrJqv1REGlqZiIP1aGmntA83uInlBs0JTwmoDVVFlB91AJartsiaM@R2gtDrUHK7DAx8dY5IdxQ5HUGuscq0LlT3UGLBQ7hwADedmE@wdFTQHjOXGI9syrjXLNJDIiS1ADQxfwjaYQj6PvMBG1epuevNh@s5DDhSbCZZ9tPVjnSZu026ypGHqZsdkywCArJlIcMbeNXCqBHQ@B8xLZmu3RKBqxzRGUzyo4nBvo44o5zKe9q0gZJLgE5cga9j8So8BHqjz8e7HLRgh5GwqBeV3fSn6eJX0YZmuIwY22RhATNnqyDfYkh/Vfnc0MaGE/MGtSOAnU@Udk9v1CgyoUCrRw28pqb@T8xDo525Uy3XNq/sWaUg4leG3MiZqD8og9FNRHd5toIbBqWAMdUkxgXSmwcfti4LrIjkhtzzDKd7umY6SfJfo2gx/AqgvxDUm2cnQYigZj@OvRFEsXWHJlnqdRCklMINUPukO1IDa7JpMugDdxQ8kgQjtghIeh0qoFql5XjIxOR1wzAHoiy1V13qas0sTabqBStF4wHdjcT5wjOBQU52AsGTGghsnu8ZS3Ohw@K0hDnV2QKUn2z/Y3KofVk92ylJyYFtJXWtA32ip9R6otLpqS2z6E2RHKiAT6W@v9CPTdMqcEa509tVPENO4yfc263u760fVow@8EITG1noDXcGiFJemADD5MUW7/dU3w9i2zJ6n69uiIZYySHp1YjUBDV8Ru4KxA7GW4AvPYXgP1wcSzUCn2WRxk3u9QAG4ioC4ZkCjYycaRUhaQ/ACBWSeUOI6QsJquIEFDPRWECbm1sfo5sU/nEhgvpNT94jcNgZ231ezO1mm8Gun3UZ9wAtOU/BVHDuRPg7OUDBfgZic@xdkmYmaC@zhWyF8fOViLr6ZqLnAHr4sx4crHvPRTcXMA/WQ5QgZrpDMxTUVMQfQw7RKmPyrKuO4PMU9tKQi8pob/WAiD3eBcOOyyxgVLcKIIBcwzbmjx5dE7DrOvo55JC1PxGIUX0hh8RaYPWsIgvzyBZdYIAj0Q7vfSjhDZ4wi40cRB22GL7B48ZwRZL2u1KFXjkvrhviiWFwHASbnxomzXmJzKqmpjYM9cN6uab0OImDg69JuiD/KS8Sb0F3J8XeKNG9By@yPfH35Ls2J39OEOPH1rgwnN8kh1LusiUhO7b67mjMRx7slX8GpX/JpwLpYwMF24YLwBAb1PRNUsT3NpnVVv2QMeCbDRUBy7Z4JBV8ax6TH848sfj1/4lTyIyKZDWL1ykRze@yqpxJyFrF4KHpX@mzKNmit9DMBOlOo2Rg@VvQabfqZA1AUc3IwLOIiE1LlFa4r4LShCTaEekNgNLtAyIBamqEkj@iB8wzzyjM5YzJRmIbaHoB6nQTzD91fAYsX8gTZbjS0h0CBLlh09zm3kkcDMHHSiZWE7NpTOEMJNhWf7jjZPSBA6L/dmWk2NtEUzsByIJV4/qeftaBJZhusq4zIyPAcdaAkcUv7wfYTSdFDP/PbmmAuB7qmEGHI9TWUTQVXNhTdc8xHjToNi8e7itVDXV40N7Ar/kB/e4TzeMktVR@0VPc5PxMi8eRkHk9taD2qETzRGCXT@4HkU1ORPD2Zc7qptAgLN7o0lRJZ2Pq8XdQhNz982i1IpyeU050xZOMlOqc7cAb8F1flvtauWh@/86lSnGSyVFZpyGrStJWGpj7CB5ZyNWiZ8f5VhyqNRcvNgR3Xv4ETXPG2rlxxZx2d8wnAq2hpnY5quc@HwG66YEeQAZS8occjrOLqWoy0Z@UxnJbOfx8CcffFeI6H6aTp9PMtDEks0oReg6TFpfe4j0zaFGF1pTFCQ7D77ZyFGZISC4Kn3IxGUxkcdb11lvEif7//cHocqil9oTA/NV/05ySZZ8Qk@WJ/nE@CUZ3F8v9Xej2MZVpP0ePpls/5oFh3J1jHrjmgNCsQb@qKDczkiOZQr6H56OcxBsfhqYlsNXY9wt7j4rjLbQ@t3IheKnpy09Q1G7uz/pAYnZ7sHueJ2y7oZ5wUfbOEbZFebHfjnmu@JDCbDi6bPMBoT5BsfMUC14R8nJMwHyJa07zB74PaRte8Vvnv/NHudm6pniCj4jqxhNacK0Bbza9xKi690898Ol7NLZfT1OeGiwWCSdvgqbxsa7ppg5GOv4@RAtRt2@a/87nYTzVNMeI0j@13z08mCtVnCTFv90BbKnrH1HP5TlKBnwcbfGC1UfKL51MlniexZPnrEstVjExDFs8HRf1V0rr6GifQZLeFi2I@5yPj7DyxJRZTHq4gGBS40j2/ctupPKVMJPmMyUMNYDW7N8rIff6E0eQh6rqjSX9EijbofZigkAeHY3Hl@6fktvJ4bq2niaQZtKtfq4Svca90FQYv@p1pUpZOyd@YQk6lni6g2vpAHahz5dNB41LFvY6PmB9PL1RKVGNJzC0mgXg4s@hB3Qoz8kmlxnEbfY8KGEXXoJN/VbuZK@/6oIv30fI@BMchOmYTdoxBf6JxJ8w34@hxynX7bs82WxOFxJhvlUj5r@tQE@q6rdL3IdV@q2eCsWz2QG0wntD@AilNg/DfCcQUMlY0JmZL5mbvrZyDLguqB7SodmXHcaL8aUIn/ZCFT8CFAlhshuqM8PchSs8Tog3T1L@lZUCWtjTa06zHcRfr11poRs0RmyjYeC7DxnmRRvuhWQw@zgjjEqiHhrTziOnsn5t6xBqcmWd/ZLTyzbp/zb6EkZqmiWyr6bofYkiaDZET@cTqo@zItVCzoeoKfwxzK4/hKyQyj@LztA6h3tIqDa7s8LWc8TJbcEr09EdALK0FtklX7ankfUSpV1qXA9t9PAg0NPE7JzqRpJWJB9L1NejrBv5OrBv5tCHHNMCachSro6I5ouNSqQh9SL66Cx5zibvbUzoqP/LwmOgYz0rg7jpuxI2d8@cninzDSxOS8f0Aj7MCdJwrdWS7z7kI34ya0J6D3ten2ab6eBOnQ7/aqRPJues8X1H3jK7ZNbpq16LO4fke6h7AkQ4/rPJYJaD8XcW@wu2EJI/G1lzX9lNXN3X9KdRFecilo2nOn6ndwqMALUj6TXhHSgMixOOrU3gwZBORaOx@qO901QGMTLbpmH01Tr6HQHWc7OG/8yefdw9CNjvTVKvF90LgzJ/iaA1dZTcaFOHS9i9Ez59IauimgjtWH1HegTLu8ylTU03T@uq8R0cxnX6fHvW@PrDph6Z44@35c5dFtk0lfQozaA7fhsJZVu2YjWZX@1qRGqriGNpV0p3D4d5H7VIhjKnmGotvYnBC14BW1iiBTFD2xx/jY/eh8c@3pjO39hsDyxp9XTBMbgHwplr5kgE6HspfrNbOiaYhH/dZufuJHlm3EIu7D3ITKdCoLMfVFGgl8oMzQBNbyoT0olXGB5SeqXpTYXwLa98ydSl2B9Aknubb4QDh8yYvHhKEO0K@gVUY3hl07MjXGbfbAp0Kf@YirHbw9BZfWrJ188Y30QxdXzHEY@6o7C1DPrYmkn10USSRFIufcXXw4OyWrvVt/svi7fRcLLOr@bNQo/mWrmieltrmyxTo@ppm1zMt3FcPKkS8aal2E2e8UfpyqchFjmF2QArHdTYGdmHnVmF2A8E83WRyhIu/31c7Cu6z29Nwy51uzw56gHl6L8FTEL8dKLb2dmA66lyc03sKnoLyjdLRmjsTreAidKkrNmXxx0QnwKDZhrjpajZtb3Yd8zsOZzNanp@NnJ5U947ZPT4R4tOLxC5TFt9l7m5Uz4HT@hivzM1rUusUK/MPCjrNoQlT8Zxbz/n7Lx6bRbgZ9PoDWzzm597Dwwr@mePeFYXbNxpIwfhnELqsq@jO/Nll3@Qp6FNiJBw7H9KyP2q62WEf8ykG6hcIOFS6H2CsdRiXDxUHeoAxh1kp/yeuW@LcRJwrNfZnYAQ1w@KaoTmPz8M4jgJ2kPvECnFVCw/jJPfwN/HiWzHET@ZTZe9RiQ9D@qipg2XzNajDD1@BUDe@PrR8ZdkFhkrTGDhxPMD42BCRe3SIKLJhPufjARZ@u/XmNOKyQqfb5Jsbv6KJ2SpYdANbH41dD67@z@EwDQ9uPyxkZ1O4psGm2lYGunOEK3pPSVft93Wc2QCZvmnOM2EORzDEPNY2fGvNEZ0a9c4X2TGxLRbCNEscbrQT7gniIG0hptNG7ukTFsQzUANUWxzTSjCCC4eVaDQSCfBEuPTTMQDMhaIznHi@ix8PtRlwh0OwWpudn7Olu2ExVZTvWZlJRYnVahwrfui00dawTwcwj3jy8yWlVl4KxeOhpdCFUWSpkAeu6iAA54IrE7BtjR68vGMSMEPhG8XR7da4xM@v2V06GwrKfguMhlOD5vLQAOGnsPgRvxPcbPI3f9kSR2Y7KlS2p4ESAgTBE@NmT@2aN895viJ3aFoFj9wiDhivdH4ALL5RZSBIwbrgJ2XNG3a6fZIX5@/E8XTwHHLt0ysFb1yc38Ld8w5vPF4abye0yNhL5VYKuu2gZ4A913K6doIda7QxfmCN96GCC8EMx0KjthVju6yl4pI@nXegeRzdNK/o4BKW5G/@kp86pFMPYje6mz2dNvbliIcbZDrq12yaAyi1i@RWtUwBEkYiw@g1wBlShgKNwiN4FoCOQwJHxt3DgJQNPxG4UT1m8S0WwpP3eMaopLXDS9Wjl@/OU7XyD6yXVP/Tz5KRO0E46bt4IWdLMeaClO6RsfzRWYgex4aYtDSUeIbekRBNdMcb3h5AIoUzGZ4KcXnMNPui19CBbjq/7HGjuFgkjG5qZ/dUYI/OghPDqjd0KpA2TBs4quMha8OGDgbeCKHmva68FB7wibz4scOykCGerFTAxU@P0yEJPOGGSZaG7AvrIpPFm7hxH3yckDoequyV191dXxn/3rzkptoY0PaT63QinSlTdZbq5bUKuSy1ZeLh5vPvL4bpVPxiuLpVS9ouUS8uht@l0u@B6qYFqZ4lsedt7W/eLSUqqS9fbGXEJOk@VOJ7CUFMLN0d7h5uHZ9UT06PoRXuXfGzbVo9ZSxrkItoK37X1OnYONDF0lT7G@SP5wPwcJgtKWwNL0SJRAL@veAEKmgtxaUl7vSJponUX0k@L72t@uJnAYRMa2vM5ahdGAawDYHZkGpY@UEfD78zkVYc4CUu01DGYwfyCIM7NufIUiKVxMpArDgQ64mkYg9X9jkPewrFvorlcbI9nwuCFPPyO/fieRXnkuD@t1LvPgyUv3m9OZbH600wj9QbQL1QN812dXfv9GhrMhnwGD1J6pYLWXEIggtn7Gl8DtA9sUwn0URCnAQtS0yiBNwrBjO67aahOjcqVEsIx2aPJyYOpfJLgTFjAmXKeGVQrcRpEQ5TCVAHKWG1ps5otLWhr4juGO1Dd8er6AmBbclD7RY8IQnMQbq@JYEftxqIVZDL7XqHJMSFvA7ZfvUn5vY4rBqO0WBfUaoHhipv1LEZ/PtGJdeVrrEhE8OZXGNxloavrhodqLALGynxMYotcUJIS7zskldevDoEytS6VGgugnYHimMoMErrSh/vKRDQ@2D/F9nngUmn6Vxh4ukXN2jpKvyWHGrapoK1oVN6hoN3DrjjFuHb3T4uo3bGVTOS736eGxg4UAGQ784aUKMtvF6oTbKe337BSW6KixbcoZImp21xsNrTEmx2rdk0eY2N0EYdRwdJibURFccLo@gcJavqNugkLRi@@fVKpJwkaE8739geN5gUBJ5MeCpjjEkBhLXLswfvYSi9acKw@oknXiI4wmz7cIbWFuNxoFxHM9wLjoo4x06Tj0XmWAPcCVIJzSRxi1AkV7zr9HQf4JwrSC7U5I//9M/4tSMXDrh/LtzD1Dr4/lD42uD@J26MLIPvn3m@NPj@iPu@T2KTzd61ILIXpteDBwCAL19IM3VCmeDe8kR18VobW/rd7iGzaSEA27KnDH3NhBIGeU4zgF5aD5jimtoYwXkO4yYc4wmfvwMWAb4C/kD1BjUayk@1amE8cV9MJrHgOFuRoF3j6pCvAtAB/M8DvHgGlLBkLptbkZNQyPi1i5BOwXZwmzJHGIkUQSYGrrV@@VOjicdRmGQ3FV0t50qcN5JLyvcZ6ZNX0CWADXBD4ZxBGjzB4qWAuIpIFl5SonIEk@JAFpJDKNNaJmc10AbD5ACQCAYb7mE/UDdNQSrgY0MdOqQxjVwDqIEXjOHspcqvH3IRxQERx43Xo0x3x/HGYzy54eugCX8zSGcIdoxgRWkes55/zy6cC6MmrslhwHi/nMO6Brj/8Zy7czhn4bng2UtbwtNXrmBt2Itjw8QN6ttQWhZOJ9OZpJyL@DhUEqigvNjVvwBK6NwgLJqqdmn27erG1u6rg8PjmctHCDI0DRZiocpa9CKeiJ3XPEfIK/ckUde3k8dv1rddUvpLNd7DgRDjjRzTxZyX23RJH8j9jO/4ns2bImYyklNPRUyrpvFt2uc0i30cm/QBbvANpzO5hiN39@e1tcqFEZzJ/su8C5mCiWVkLnBd2HQdU2i6mFjEXXcf@wle9Ggn3BNOaWl83Zh3Lov7x8EPXx/iXRs5vkPE3TEfoDO443O6iQf20kPdE0meFV2gwQvmlhdkjVtUGYs6zrAZmNmH4y8NE3WZveFSHDLziHTA55Dc@wltDmmTcOazTHSRj0czD@7ExYhdf3yrh7jOogul07VG4EacvHaP6HmnrhN2X9eccCRgCIjpw3qzkPajl2N4YEr5fMi8U2c26ozDBM3ihunuqZtagN8twtwrQKJ0i8jhAOh2aPbZeBZtU3VdR6BTsc0Bn9VT2atBD@Da9DhScbRQQcuKQ2KgZ8gtyjnemyEokei1suFhJNFVhy2tAyNOOBID0fSdLI/vH1HwAg3QqxrzaoDTUv2uAnXApsms4fUdw8hagbzjCvL5RHYzP9ioBQAZJm1EinzmInRquFdFYcMXWSjmUaYRiYUSjFtS4hYo2ktAE1EJttHFnZc09dFua6Sy@U/188G8rVm9BNYKhhnOQi9x37Wfa77pKhgfZZRzJaEZLXUYxlP3xRrSCcJDN2fXoYg0w@J0H424faQ1fTGNKwsVRwil8aUuU/KuUPDk3KRoKBTw5D6eXwSjBHI8dqw9cIKKEG73lD4LD@hmH5slGHnDF2EjZjtWhMUrOFzfMINFozSnAQ@KAJsFQdvk0ugKhTBehBdOlqGRMNQ2Wvi41frsXE4kauCmTCJsCeczN0CbwpnASABsVEhSJLSgX8BfEUvEry1NiOtLlyjbAF2uAVBzo0lO4YQ9yBegBdWaVZ75LiUYCxhO1UKhKFpjUtoXGPDF2hyBCGjnSHHXRgD6ivNmQDWU0QC1YaktDeTli9eqYahAIOCZHt7SqgyAyaxIzL1AODa@4I9yCPIi7ogDbFDQyYv/tkJ3ugnq2lKyRFNjpXtQaz5doF7TFprNKPnfJhPJ0l14SS@PkqBrRirhpW5ZjmaWo9ElYzm8ZKC29ewZzqjdL4EyV0@AgToEoPiSHikBP4PyV14ySkvKWnipVU4vUwrwgol8Bwl@sJOJuyXlPrn0DJSlGIRYXOiEl2y6kyeVSMj3UD7sIUvJGPDMHV4uQ9cCY/ZLWjSKZUgs1bEAPyQvjqM0bF4cJ2nyriRsgWSnJ7rblCrmtcTMdcacgCK46A1YWRywxGbEugs8vvYvMy/uAfWPZ/wat2wz2mmi2n7jS5qMebpgEXIaZa4QMmF@KRIQcBgGIqI3pkQiIEx@/eugnGNMep7LhM3o82yqFA1lZTDTwb4OvgA9PLksWdLdxWb8mqntdO5z/FxpJz7XDq8OD99HLsKswELBjQNJXpG@x5ubn/ZZZekHPuynf4LB5WQgmFyWn60mk58@fQKLAz7nlUQFxAf/RM7jodp5eJWxyurqciyXX469CNV9xYqE0@nIMdO0JLvQ@narBV@zS3d4h4P88/w55QXmP/wzHibyFw7XgyAiNPiNcNdKNsguVhVlObqSfmGUEulU@m/@3eJ97O6wvvY3v9dLqov4OMDHz@/foPtYzn63uPjd@vrKSgwIyd2HHw8/VKvVlc1Y9vA8@3wlnlpc@4//x@JiOr2WTi7WbFuuhc6v3kvp1IqU@Ju/CB0evq3bNhCigJ8Mk8GJv3n4yiybZVfsFj5XbYb/5L5t@dwKuhvtW7wICeyVMgmbUCibCR1/H5rfbItMrjxf/c9/fPA56AQr6eSZBU8n@DmYywe5Exzgy7i@62AluIZgufvgKFkul8G5@p//V0hfeQV4MGa0Bj@VrIsrNwpW4mVK8iVYyYFDTqch3//rZz8LBCvD4G1QluXgiP7q6IZP/pn8jKEjKa3mJdN8gbeM42fo@4xrkZTl9IXbnr7mxqb1gruAG9qVmb4wr909rmKCG8jxVLgK/Gzh52//97/907/9Y/r7U/r@B7y8Orf44tMmYyqMwPgpFl/MtMPelP8oEYdPwusdQfTGRc2C@XKszkvlsXDQ55iig/fLBEk8/zfCBYLuDawoh2oTjXERlPMrBy@GT/6wcaFd2gbHJPUyZ9NhbmN4HubKAvYtcIHgD@XykYN/bxr4d2jjHxv@lA@yw3P4LMIf/cPH8@LvIoWIYAKZ/Sz@BtI3EDwPntdqOwb@fe7Sn4V/jc/4t3eLf58d/Dtp4t/RZ/w7ucU/NlObQHBtbS0YjR6ByiiY9imfU/gmEnXh85g3GAj@Vj9s5SB38CIAfaIWjd/fnye@H0ZLJfEPylTJ8@GHu6BYtft4fO37SjR6TsU7r4hyrsVrFSgrLzL9fL8GiKNr52triXqlUonXvq@cr00mEulevIhiR30BCSu18/NA8A7boow/y/jTtPE3LUlJ8n5BuQ4DdSEQRB23wFXdgghg9PoF9AeCn9Y@haPPo89Teuo6JV/JV2/Mg/H/wcEQIrRh6tK0Ut1UV26BqGQp9TQ1So2GqZ55ILfAqcJfqgdOLdUepjopI2XI8mg4gerh/96B6bw5MAGbCSmdYcpBxKk2PDsHB28AXxvyvoQ/LZVKDaGQw9Q1/Kd0FNx0sxs9v69HLgLnTPqkglqQkEOJVCiRC4W0WjbX/yzFQvWL81CtFEzaFxdJrjCx9EqJbvS7v6/Xt/Y36/UkstDaUvRFNP4CPuVKdE08ngcrpecXxTg2HWe9RD2YXHt@UcnE0Z2LQvukIWwtGf3GzxglPCuLFwGwAc/O8Ht2c33DXeQg18XZmReLP0kMIhcFwQdAk3PTTzgYKJ@/o//WwX9Z/29OWfi8FmEsfHe/FqZPBP8ikbv7u3vxW4mEw8ITXoM/DAA/Jrm7r6CTgO7AdR6O1CL39zwMfsORNY6wgnmsVSjxGBD6apDnehEqMQbGUliss11cDFOpSKkBId6Mu/KFlmwiJdrMstTAZTYwEOTlCIFkV0qlFeFezZdKeeGWc7lSadmDSoFHOAFItZVmCRm9FOxHsAyc/cMpnGeha1ND4Zbaxvvzn/f7YOzJhdSXL15Qvd7SrHodwzNfvlxATwrhXpZyIQshqfyXL9D9QhEwBPdNsYpaALNOTqbH6LuKrTiOFQZTP3YRwk1s9kUogvHpVAqBMT3Lrq3lViqV3Aq4c/lIpCQt8Y0w4U60IEful5ISrwaYaKGgiJLzqxEKvQ9hPAuusecV4HAbP@zuPkjUZivZSLgxUiNegFwo8BC2kgvnowXxV16MsLVkZZmJv/PzTHRleXX5Ra02HrpQTJTulLJ8X75TijhvcF9qiktLcc@o8uxZpgB0yadKF4F6fbN6Uq3j2x9wTRqkL8NAEjgBXG/sW6FzmuTJFmrnWJPaRShULL3gDZvPsmCoJODiIRBdLF@gCgfBktTauFl8SFj5tygvpzOLyezwu9xWCjTvL8v4OT8/z6fz0WUQbcuFQq1Wo9Avi5TmvDds1@jyqnL8XM5la3HUXS6H7eVgn8mrmeByoE@7i1ZTrIULtBZOmi1CILQra@Bauq3quntP7I1p6a0braUC9sO96sbWSSy9BijT29WNWPr4dD0oozc79lN0Bv1HW9XNg1NIcLi3VT3eern7buv0EMJtGCCBWPDpHSrqQK2rN4PBDfrrKn02NFu5vFT6/XofPsP2j7/8gx9/@d/9@Od/9OOf/8GPf/6nv/rFn/4BfP8Svn/En3/0bwtZ/P3VL/7Z//zjv/5zCPwP8P338P13v/rFv/gZ/5L/r@H7f/rC/lp8fXD8C6QEbH/4q1/88V/86hf/5F/C91@J77@c/v74J/8b//@P4g@df/7jn/w1/gjPH/zRj7//xz/@/u/9@Ps///H3/yEg//u/@iX@//Ff/f2//yX@/y//5u//6n/4@z/8n8jxZ9zxf/@rf8t//@73/uDvfv@f/93v/eKB3z949PcXTwj/xe8g5OnlfAqep9TrW0N@8ZPK85tQY5wLMdif/uMf/8U/As79E@7778EH/17Uzz2PFxMlqy4eHQf@nLEvSdCbUi@@eKCA8n/EUAhmXyaxUWjKDf3VL/75X2DwBOw/8mNIybOwSwjs5fZzgP3XXsH8sD//8Zc/@/Ev/uGPv/yzH3/5hyjQ4iuFWDUWl78yMQSA2SfAIWDuKXAAKK/hGvkiWwykwbG4hhMZATn66ROQdBFcoIAvB7IZ8KEhM/2p1Sr4uThPVi6SFxX@qYE/kaxgSCJ5kcT4RBJVerlCyKBU0QDkDAbRMp@JiOIEBHyHgZUC@HBuIgpDUJRHRSFqPcrK5XI0MCxDHIGCF9MMWSWPVhcaHWXAi4l4mlg9D1otG64TFkhZjh6x@nJ5yBNGMaBCGBgWCIOOJDktRfPlTciwPNxkiAuRRwOf4PmpXMmXhxVE9wMVAXBE1yFLgCpj6YaVH8BfJpwAHxhu/gBFyZej0UoeQspUVcotVqc85SxVjuoeZVRvDAcLGB7PXzD2nSTnJW78QVswAY2/0TH0c5oDeQ7xF9FlUR36d530Xcb00NBDog8P4/HPMZjSCwDAG4/jhiz4xuNYmhcQPeSoopQtPKIcA1AuKuaQvAAapqOBKLVvlDyQP5ThaZ@1is@D6LA6S0tL4FqrSBnpAEwJZl0VbUexcL2ClKQik3IFCYNxf4u6dEjGxvLmMvzK8L@1SHtUOTmWA0sh1AVCzM0jHs2YK2aQSu9WjeqyTCWPElwgOA7nCi4tOoFmusIigTDdnB4hY1Xt9@H5xu6sm0NQQmOSFJNzfFo5ImzZD2axWP5BXlkNwJP8A7y0XVwfDs2AL/JKYC9Dglbu4tTj0An6Si5QqYiFMyYHKsdbJ5Dg5IDJ6VSCgeZ6t7KaXsmuZNOZXC67mpZXcoWVXDafARGXS2XTabmwslLIF1bvqUgvQFTEisuN7FrlH8x8/pt/MO8zPxQ/gcp7Nkyw@H2gMozHk2kqcVnOrpZGZSgHBQUqpIlxHX10F8f9koEL2p91h1uBoFiBuziy6QJ8WGAhwBYgCD6AFpcMmFjH3j0oiQU9fB0GX9ST5CwwQiRwAYzAsQX6k58ANtszkDXPZO7M5sbOFDpP8DDWPuQAjWCwPdw66ZjsxORb9NbVZmBNHCOqBAK0/nEOJK0F8Lb581pgLenFzse00eXviNuwTNBwfzrMumJc8ahNDe9@bDpe1I6CNzzZPc3pPgBx2u/h0RbV@p1h2Oo1oIA4z8kB1uHH0k1zHsAqOz18oJZvvMOduJBIpzsB/Gj35c6J73myVd3YCeTY@sH@5tQjK4CybG9r@8TzrvJYN2nWQ/Fha29v2iseaKUssuxqLAbSEX7wGaMPPRNL37sgcuLhcTcVAzOqrh7zdySYNnRXGbh6qSCDXZjOrqYKmUK2sNq0yuvRo/ogLz1flDJgijYV1oFY4PxTYzBsp/MgfpoqdK9SMFXMpfYHvYHlaCtgQb0H@yXwBveVFWR@PkKzAztg4PTwJnm8dMAJWGoLjJ0bg45@NPB9UIM@ezAQHhiETkvrdCHnG9MFCDQUhcH3Wz@QXvV/nMcDHJ4Hhc3E6HPAcSVNa7NUIEGTYelCPpsvZNL5WL6QX8mCHZiNyemYvJpfLaRickrOy7l8tiDH8iuFzAqISIiFZggEQZRo7WQSRgBZkuipGU287XUNr801E91KIMjnEmDYxRcdBhUvYJBnUiZ/kYJ0UgD3zDKtvCjhq0RT@KJOQKiwJgtub2@ktrclaR09OOW3kZKkFnqy@VRqdV2SVIrZACmeliSTp4EoAHO4J5Va35CkAUeA51MlqYuerRzqq5KkoWejur2N@VyiJ43pAeyKx3CP7npWAcxATyZDCq8kffbQAVyVZ7RCJd1CD@aJMds8ZgPiJOmlW55UCjAccTiOYceta7UqSbvcU61izCuqeJYX9TV6qvSRJAs8wIOS1AFHxwLLXJIa4EROlKQmuJojBcJ64MKjjIajSNKIEwhJJElDglaaVxLoViIcs9nZ2VG6Tkvt8M/I4s8mFA1itOFga7vx8mWj02lYo@rWyyOMefVqR7kcDaxGpyGSNerwMSENxFz1RtMfKONuva7oc2NeQ4wxFVMf1VUsW135DGUSnw5m0qu/gphXEDNvJYVjg08PQBv4We/Bc11pUIz7oRh6DhsNqYQ86oz6Kk65YJehvUclf0hPaVpmCV2gjLPFUDgUG53LtdhtiWJYj7Fw5C5VukeQdpjeEoKyEjSfu9H5sJyqgQoul3A2KLzYey7JhaxUXFSeh4fozklFUMJXpEgR37BitkMsFJefgwDMrUrFZXhKz6UMOIfhVCjFGPxEzldrz6VVRCI9fx6XoCzgBRAFEkqrBURYWAWFoHQP9HBA4jYGjlqvh8M3qnIVifA68bcysbOzs8gd32@lUR2dUjs8jA3LvDRMi5RuofDTmFoqDHyDpmNaHF8HKHD7PFWkSkL2eQlyZ8lkZA0FEooQeH6i6ewEK8b5@0jkfC6SwN3ZdbNdpzcDsE/unPfZ2Yxr1g@a4hkesqADlu5uHFKS7WLgBNVJet0hwyPhDXxDEJ1pBTuF301B7/NRQbksBAIVoV@dqEMnsaPizphmSYRt8AOLCd8hWiDKR62P98uX6LAsnnR8YxpKi4lgdkPZ1yuVcr18e16Lx7G4a2tkVEJubiIYwNi6AMbDEu5@8Xp5HQqWKhl4E4OK3qVhcBiotBRHAVtt/W5QLALsfalTPsfEX/BnLS5VJMjq/EsNdFFotlFQKduDBp3YZ6kGKMu50hDC5NWVUhvYmeajhzBa3mXleEVO50vZdLyCUNkMPlfvSzpTyvwwyBJtCVNK/rKHIyXCWm6H9bBjbhlQnVSxiLVSyhXywlOJRNPLerhlMmUtfgv8Cp0B99tDD4mUwouRsq1@5hryFx3nRBfr5RTXlZfsQe88tZiTY3fxevxeV2xnSV5NF88HS@dxuba4mPrSWZM@Qq2h2vcBUKv9U7YwzJUgzOU/PjCOh7ZxWL8EOoyuApHkQrokQAJ90QnCEgvj26r4PqRwKLSaDoUioRJALUIw9aXIHbF@CDpk6Bl0QxhaoR8W0hBvqc4AdDsQEDMl4PZATg4E7wMtze6zlUIgeBe4v7tfq7iq02s2GinRuOt9xlgnCpZhkpaYcHFqkVzxROUFq5arnaNqSYBWN8h@SwbYBT/dFk8ufutCVnSt8j1/XuD6JWQT4MShZd7kWrRC8x0BSZKCkrsKEc5nwejDqZUfgnRDJNu4aw8MujWi@AbJpRS5Jnhei/ywr@l3eWA3siqAoe7vg9G1JK6NJipJIlbzgLYOBIKGKZw4J@1AVwVZk81KaGGqrH9c@H71@/z3b04PTg@22YtUMV/Mc0pccKMvJofkEFD2BSg52tFWINj/YmblH4xXpWCxH8qshDITSutFWZztDiMfhM9x2Qa@tXOwHWsRcJXL8nN5tajZYlUlXLQHfdWKPJdz6WI6JUeCdgUPnqZXg0AkdMm51WAtyJGurEbATQsCaTlYSYpgeRXTxbkPWDgbtAtfgulUPhDMv/n0hTH3JbtamlzJpCju0v3aPfxX7s/Bar4n4/me/vEnCT/3HID@MYHrocf4MwE3hhnH136Ir/H/NfrZOOAll3LQFMFP0N9t@/v69/VgIFgIVaLJEL4wnn@GwiBFZXXZoD/VXsa/78cBy7ZtL3s@8C5DnVm2IjNQb5PJi8jbNCi2hUIunwsGfj37SS6D@by8UGUhfg0THxjwEkbveFNo4rVXOOOxvBDfPD7YeL11giODauBrS9nGwX4Co/DNmuPzaU1dVSx9JF6tOUIoHFBONg4ZGDOnm4eU5oxOJlIoTWyIXJZ2W0Xx/pnYNZMTGVwtyyZTK0k5y@R8MbVaTOeYAsLIxpsIhGsJkzKq1obZH3FzJLwRocQLVYTBuD0NTEVbLbKXh3uUgi4pWF7Y3HpzwA729z4k3FAefrKze8yOD7ZPzqpHW1CPN1vHTKoes91jiZ3tnuwcnJ6w6v4HBtFH1f2T3a1jRJAMoCBD9YgTzLMN2Jo9spOoO9lkIEwE22bzSnUmwxWrryTxVtHJYANfOqLizfyT4QMDRtaW3/Y4ri5wRYQheqXVsgJ4JFJrsgU0PBaWVQv3DUvdlL3KsoP3tykru8iaK/uhVdZM7RuZtVWmp8Qf01d6mSO2uLh4YUjeKOCvhmf6@INwMz2Ejcu0@3FrIZxbYctg8KRXIuOY/YPDhZTrWzg7OlmQvbijzYW059ndXsh4ni3wrXi@7bPNhaznW6@@XsiNk@1vLKx6vs2tjYW85wMmXSiMce5vLsipgEusa1NrLdCL1cLbu3tbbBmAIqWJWJxuQsdUMBAiPDBsfj8F2XrLyzddM0aac2M0Bd1Svwbtgk9ALaDWc450rcXYstmHn57aA2BIFvBUWcXqNGMCK97AA2NL4C6wgBVawAoB/AKejEY4tlhm6QiD6IU2X7gP8xvZYkw6ten843c2W0OltALMEKMrfegcLKRQxRsWAwv3AmW4TVNybdrcS6BgHzDJkiIRPDy3f7q3xzOD0cEyrbBEkIw80hycZh@wQRXhF6sOobxxeLNQWyCtFoRqgW@BDNxPtGZgujWRFFDPhYUmIJik7rWixxiqVjFcEEa86OGb8gEYosGdAhc/NRgON7GuHdVpUoEiSMytg21eQ1xSLrPJVo4wzJQoRdF8u/@XL8z1XTiTXmvSa4Q4boGcF4vj4yUtI2wEwxbc45oEQUfTKeUCckw0CqmhOhTnq9cCEB2@/CS7W8oKZJQKsWfPqBxr4CuEKAtMF6UcWRxBEIEgGJEPkXlFW6TiRhaSy7jjg79CHYmI4wi/5LMx8m7hAMk6XdCpVvV6odecCwaYYqUpgSyi2i1sa3Bn0nXwo3gETo6xBnSTGHMj5RxGoqUTY2qMtSF4SqbWNQM4V7XGMtFlBeiM1Pr7m7yF@JUzFM4DqMYg94rUYCAsnmH3JUZfWGhYYJCWXCiQhwQFfItME0ZCcLjH0x1tUrJl3l@QLTH1U1LubhddPuKpgR0EpxFZ8ZYAziuiuhRYGQPN4BfIsP@WAT1nSY4sGhUQHpcJsK1JuHicw927fPmVSmxN12Lxm2uBYvnBWmw9sRq/WS1gWBuzCNQCRHwY8EYBmn4mWzM9DwWMhYSCavPTUMAAOuYl6OMTCJ6QHobccfr4t6eHQbo43ZWh30ILcqnAk0x6m5Pe1qQXuy@EKAxsgvQK@8Ia6JJz4MLT4iwPjhaXlZMJ25NemggpM9VN0/YkMM8BeA5FJQdDBpwVxihBEja@kEDp4Wtxyqy6Xd/d3zqZjEV8CbsuCt7F189THpFJMFEgjLfD6Il4JQq3kQhc3wwf8jxiRM/68cnRVvVNDMoXYWvjHjCtA8CP6AkTNbh3c4BQQ23CeNyKsfBxlS1H2DMsWYyJGQP0PDkL3bRVQPVgjq1BP01ZpTiI55/sSUHskYE5WUlhFo6wLxcXMKSmVpnc63/J9DLGaqbFRplVVHY5Hk8HEVLeFTD7vGtyZQMhW/z2ueLczC5TKbZiZZijdkHjHqasWfxUr3sc22hYdM@09k0yyuwSwyPEKFvEDSAwLk6qNo9rkTQ2Ih9gKHZjCMPhnObOoqSfI3tSrKtg8bK01G8ty9c02smyxHlZ1ijT2TL8Wkw4grkUmDq3TBepmH2nr@DRXhF50McZlUMMsgIBPtPiu08rbOKrSJxIke5BQZlSr@O1k/V62Fb1Nr4GfWA1YchHddkWYPjB2ASPpI6EjslIQR7UnyYjWhoexcXbQWHUmUJIb2Mv0@19YcoxEPBKZjtqn0rlKwZOluFLe/0ZgoE94YdmxSNyvhJHikIr3lawP7jIzieuQOI4BnY3NicYxPNsqMemc@I8tpkThzfdzUviHt2eE3c56M0rAQiGB2LE4cs5MYZ5MC8Bv0FoHFE79xHw3E/gWi0cmd/00K8mW9x3BRTR/8QaqOI@o90DHwuCcik40NfWwU0VmLap4QXv04i849@QMjyM@E6ie2wVGXOSYjc1bRq9i0kgoqOUdIc5GxabXcD6nZzOR2I@hD6MeEVhT9Efwsl8SKGEc5AE2THxvjsHanuokQWn8Y7TJ/AiBaMF5t04gdl/BB5jx7DY@C7wAt6B5cV4zDyny43RFWcZh8Jx5h2bX564LewhaLcScsRP0N80@/i3Zh/35Y998idlXWbnk@WoRX3@IgSM6@h28J@UkVvqydwi31RjP9eo6tUD7Iu3uviy4bc5TGbroRESyOMptyqEHgOeKCQQlx/RN8gXaj5x1nxe6vH4s1xmcdlLwyXeuDfQ5Lqv8AG8h6Jexwtc63W6ua9ex5mlel3iOdDAiwOef9AVnY3HJUBLrZsUG5biihST4vHq8cbublwzpBi/M7ss2Y5pqXW8gEuK4SpqWSKBVUeYrqr3y5LY5abYjFJLD@dR9eUBFfx6JgTEc9k1KJPxzaxfz67pr5L5hCqZU5mNb4t8Qm5HlBsejH8sJ4tfu@ZmtEE3g@FVa5aqoaDht4GLN17jFRoTNzfglL4oAs/Xppk@G@/L4EWiRx3DRFvjxRO0wFtmNNsnuTfJSDMXv4jejlM9iGDMqZz7pEN6ZxCjW8VaqtCzaHooIY1vlBQFS4ia@vjdVdD4RRzjAW3ydhlR3pg7N2njNOZUUceCxexj5c8lvHwGGuDQ7MOvdwENuL0raMCNl9BgkCvqwI030GCKtnCIy2jARdfRwBPYWxrfftlThlpvgBM3/isOhCY3LhYO@VgTGvUpclL6cYoiRELHa4TDAm8kKhUlqLpNV99MX3@D8PNuwInUArNClu5rxmL6VId5SOfeqROJ/RYayaeIoWi2RWkgbUxiEldCKK1crIHx6eMdV8Sg@jwVZvJZT0QENYl56cfjle8GnfKEeYEUAeOBF2acgM8y@d/NR8p9pOipIOMW80NxxW1OuXGb6oMF92NwFbVI4BFL6v83dpK/Sf4LNZX@vzeKZkyf37Ep84gJ883Wym/RLPivCv1/Veh/gkL/W9PmH1DJp1HO9vgpdf2ravi3q18k80YwbFida5x6S/8UPey3pAisfpMe4Jb6XH5MF/j6@OyiSfuH9Z84Sgd@nTxp5c62zWq1etKTraOX1U61Wz3Cy4rWU3vRs8uV9c2b9ZfrrermZudVZ2NffZuvruz1X7/Pf3jZvv2sgva@c/Dq463eb3YD74/6N2fq4U1GzdvVweDz7s7I2Vk/7W0cZz@s3qS29Gx7Xf28qdubb07evz55mT2O3nx@dfjqtpfq2YftlFLoZXbe5N5tjM6MQPZaO21t72kHvePW1mm6t7epfdiObqT2jgtv5dTe1s3HzMZNNJtK7vZfH7w8Or1sbH3Uj3b3PrQ2PptK7vPVTX832Sq0Ny6P3gUOMm/lnc8HB52tdOHlTvJms91vpdI7upW9fH90uH76Yaf7WtnqbWdPC@8vR4e57tu3185@tLNylhu8sVeiRvXt2/Rr4@X19dZRoKGYJ1ZGPTPfyv2bm0Oz0FtVX@/vdHpvLdlIHmTfRY97JzebW@v659Vh5vTD2dubleMPgzdvX308SGnHx40tJddvtNLHlycrgWYvsxu9Pt06zSsvW2dve9e7O9kPm8k3XXW/2jrUr152dj6ax4d7u9WMPTDkvY1r/cPL7uWbq82NXd08vNKN6koyq5@0PhwcBE5faY1Ndee9/ap62f2QzK5frXyItvovTy5vu1ev1o9PD/Lp4eEoZW7YR42d9nDzKJfOJ5v656PbtvlGPn0bzV1fvkprH6q3TiBzO8oW9vQPas94FW12Pg4/68noqSxvfNy9/fDheOfaalSN08/vto8urTct48A@SB29ev2moV/lncv@R@P4WG6mXqpXb6IpJTA83bGhjdQTJbt60tt72x9ump@Pdj/audvo9dlVRt28OnpX/XyUatwY/feGtaf1NlKtA6X6znS2BsOXzcL16dWOvvf5wP4QeLMlZ7PbZtteb79bKbxPvoy2r16@X5ePh6l946i9krP2370907St7vvT26NmdvtdP99zjM7b29PeVnRrb9i9VfOphn784coInGaPjw7TN8Zrreds7xy9yTkHqb13h62dkVx9q8o3xurGKLs5tHKZs8331oerHaOf/KB9Hhym1Oto60PfWXmrNdrNd1qz9zpw/Kp7un/47mY3m7Ne9gxt/TCf2t/b2djvtFZej3bfDLb2Gpetl7vv1ff9k9xVemv9LLf5/jjjnFy9dgrN617mMB890XtO5zQaeDXoDlYPz6zP74YfV6q9hpo50j@Yo1W5t/Gqnx6@q24d3HauDvvmvrydHiVP98wrPXV7cnO7Y@eqo2h@eOr0TOdEHmblt4HMzW3fedV/9fb4YP3VwcdXyoqmnSmXx@9aqcxpPql1rcxuLvdS3tpu9z73Cqp8u/kmo2R63ai9d5VsbbRO351d6Ze9173LZiBfsJvrux8HirnVSMupD@vtray6t753IqunndfHK5v7qcP3rcPTz8OT1sb7wem7Ay21dfmqsNdZeX/0rvB69eOJfaKcme9fW/uBYT5j2nKukL3JHBfyB13rOHN2WXA@vr7MretnDfnVbrqnbmvW@/wof9W/7d50bo7VVKPzcvOzctTeAkl6ephSsoOr/eFxIPPupHe92l@Pfrhqvn5vyHr@TFtNnny@LFx1u69vNpsrZ9Xbz0r25aVaON5ONvTt7Mvo0cbbw8vO5tltfqWVWt97p7wfbnWdD4G3O9rmZeHs6mA4kt9uH4961ZShZ6@Pz7LXJ@b68dnOcb77pmG1GzuXXZANvdHp5c3gekdd7Q5v8q@7l@@U1N77/IZhrxymAq/U3V7r6OT1@2q0nVYLzvXBh/3@Wf5smH2TN88K5kFee11tvxy@PWhvpVb72tnJ8HSrm1zf0Hp5kCmH@qm1cfB25@PZq34qkDZy67cbZnb1c/R6@CF3ljyM7g0@NE/SvTPL2nmvWdvvrw/fvz6u7kZ3G6OXh1fKwYet7PH@xob9Krqt5dTRTubGrm5k9LYZsHvrw/2h1S9kPl7tdWAkMFuF1suTzJlhV6vtm9388Va1@tJu7L5ShsOX7VUYI/CzdfbOLAd@zS@iC/A76PhD4ZdeBHp2p2EOQV7yY3MBOv0UoNNPAX7eifZJ8z3Iv04uB078W//pzbJ8gmfQAGWNtUxUHhJs17stFl8WEWM9E5Jr6GqafXoiWnG@oYUGnw6/NF@FB/PovXjqsK@bGr6HB98JgDappfLTf6C@JAIHBuuN0N501B4/kKDhq3TE5a70GgH@xiK6XDKw0Gwy9@2BCbq61HuX4CdQIPpGJ0531XZYPN5s60rHBofeItenwLF3lzrmoGsKTn5gFvJeXZFTWbE1lQ4rYOFO8A1A@y@ZbvKXFLgWhwLKxIgu/MBJKrr0Q8U3jNnataqP6K0TaisR4Ds@n7QL0h@GG7wnw@iCzam9oaBuqNbUBtA@T@iutCaXX@B9LC@Wk2KJFZWhumI1NAffX1vn5xPqPEd3z1t/cu8hnZcVC7RcMULNhq6mjYljPkP0TaVCitFGczxX4IjsUTVEFdXdbbi83CeUtO@KcY8P83L/Ydxar/PbQj2Bu6WpE3hNoNUAaEUL0jNr9t/ZtMnRAyoF@GL91vvdk7p4NQnfYjhxeOiBHZc@KpdcX7/Ea@Arvyj57LZM3GEAxcdpR36zM1T12uS8LNG@R9weCa2NFvZ4tyW9nx2Ljtj6tBvlfKXGdxCmaOueS3AvzTPOCc98pXo2JuiC2FDh8cAT0/ENmhxktr6IuG2pKgHQbk73fMjUZr/fMu890DINXTGu0FXiW2XBXrCavsaily746oFTWV5dxP5JshGw3pDU2wY7Lqhkec1CAGJDrNvMpwZ2Z9pvj2l4C3tZ4/wY5uFZXbpuNsPj6GV3yw2vW8TNicNPZXWAM4lt3FlrWiOeEU7PhEslAMF9OiQTVMPdreqrdXlMDURHm3p8pQC@LblBeDhfHZczxh4vLc9qkdiBdgDNLyrfDIRQ516xajyrh2Uh0Dvir8xE0jFx3C1E4EwuM8fsAxHaguNgGCMe4btTZ6jCd3p5XMQ4nc5TNfhnz/2eIt@4ix1KxWlPFCER7MZooU8Vzis0gla8roNZjVmPGgp3cGMTasSLTAMLH8OZFo1OtJMP@bmGdJNZlKgdnhMLYsirkSC9oD3B0J44aA2@FZe1@Q4uTuvAFInWIKMvX7wOA16PGw/dE4vAEt7bspHBOWfyviwIWnL9bif03BQzJoonVe9n99LTSU0wwM2bvjZU9TAIzDq@cqXPIEhsWer3uYMgvO1LEIyNTWUX8mpxMQypzgkuma@xZywsr62FV@NhCvouH4l4nVEkT/uS@xKDkK5UWDi9HM64iVcwMaDMTCJYmY8gzRGsLIdlF0FaIJCzgIGrGITkO5bnXDuJOO9D7OGtTcLgi1vm5L6cjsq1tbU87vH0BU4lTs8v@nImmobEHPVCdDKGo@URvvDaZI0AeSbtG0d8KFaiGUDBs45ORoxznYrwMvXnuVKbOzj91pQX95yGO/hQcnx/pGqd57G@yKl8U3qfgbvvWCIQ3@HVpzd5jcM4Sy8jm4OOQF0ScuuqeGgqxt/kJgYtoF9palT0HY4gCBQDRAQXjxZjl4@NdY1vH@wQuE0TfLzOMSbHWB7MEJAoIDHykBhECNFA69Sbvb4HB0NxPsJ3fPMBjDLZxxVnPD8A7YRqv5sTiTFOPlzhBnziTVo0hnD6hiFBfW93HR/vto5wx@zu/ktowgWsR4yNf91qLnKMXhU3FIO/3UNzNCgCyDZu0Ii68qaazB8D3fwFNhe5gJ/GzhNS7RCC8cRCOyS@0Jy6ZgpsnJQuH6kO0ZFeNuUB5CMlsDPYjcoUHckx4i/JzfN3UtGhN0pNpAKHl1AUECmENDs5qu4fbx8cvSHKHdare4c7VcQMBmZTsVqM3pqCHcQwVJ0Pqh49Azj8dvBFzFgnpeG@4oO/ohph@ev3OPEAsE4xdQqdLhHWlzP9DDwPnpeAJIoHDUpFvaX25@DGvasemKiMPQchb0VeajEUijLNGwlpwJsdCV05WkFJR7Q0VdsIOcDY9BYZxeDyJOniWwcrk17BRz0X9agO8YvF3zmWSdOLiJGP7EEfV4fVluQnv9JsqjZdETCmPqBU9TZlIiSLj1AQMr/2Y/nBz6Z4Y6/AQe9hpEE35em9YzV3UlkE7ZHT7ifpuD4FiWNxdaQ7V60ktUjkzN@LPKE6apMq40OZ8dwueW6XkBsXuOxyWiHTaueXE4rYPPJoLnkuuW7samZcPfG2klPLtaHT2128tofmQrjUoQbDZqIrK8zRhKx75jbZM7cXj3vifOXucaVMEHZSIxMDznj8FAZzqwVkC8/MbdDJFbK@Bha2P/cY6g16aKTkB51cE4PgiVPqoE67cK74xDNUD3IGYgJpSKdlzkV2NRpUPHxhgZDF3fJEfLoGncIUswKaAdJifDhN1JVUSdMWhqIvEMWqGIWtltvJCXI8mFmt6QNdCISh/MDh@FQCP8bHM8qjk97hWCbUyCFjnZUiuK4aj0OCCJ/XIJ0GxC3WgYqnOfOrkZ@thqicq5Np/AQMijrhlrkoQNAvYPdAqJt5aW69ffVwD8Nh4oivYqmSOEHhnug9PWQZOZPxHf89ONtnudz4dDDeBMZW0qnxkWO8E4zlCoGfNE82nk/g/IgdRzQoshXyDJruoAuqug6dmD9aGg79WDZuFg/5Y1TylKtlbsHaQhyLocFmPXw7fEPFt6Djeq3D5KGcCCyAUKQ5YPF6SXfwBsDOQLEUw1H5GUsU5GJlFzOkhKjDqhbUC18LT2@fB4mPL0eHYcFS@QQwhLTMJm2SRByUDlp60KPdSDFUGK5VC68B0Bxx0H@BZI5gBy4aKpwJ3EBXOFRc3uAkFCKBejROsnAy0rCM1ONTL8KVJnXlZC9FpTzZk2lIc99UiwUg8gpWIRpzd2BBEHhmmCF7fFm8rsvtkh7wWPTPmxqcHWS4cera4QINH2NmLX@tNmcyhrir6R@DhmITE6GiOtUi7hk4kgDuEaimOw/BgegxrNHwRLi4NYoUxHfXa3wunJGMIC2CRikaUizkOtylI26Do@gF713dxM9l6H0RsTNgJA7MeccjBQSyfIRDiLOR0xDYPznE0I8DSsE76nJyvP9giDi8824ovolDXCsc3RFhFyACbteS2sXLz8@kza@F6KOUKT@SNl1Sior4@vJ8MF5lAYa184FBoUgeuZVywU4Px@feXEAqPU1IPVb4idyeWniR3QzQBCWeWHSPEPdirm4eUkjcM69VvkglttUINdPXPlxJgkYUjEA8S/1eTFUIGrhSgZeu4UvBdWY3jStJKEYc@p0VOQLKcyyn3ePArkD3pjnH53rnVZRzsltVt5rUgvS@bF3r09A4WVfRLfx1jcuzlV31VdY9ZTxRWZHIrefs/Q4GONq6ecPvX8ABRRInl6XvWjH2XQsXQ0SIf4xyqTFP/k2edfZ1yO/L4x7p1c8rKx2a9Ty8r4q1QxTtfn7HdIg35XZyfGEyDQEygptGyd1cz1MtLAh1BpSeiXTpiJh29tjZRdFug7ymrfp49@te2sU05hjCUmY/cDw0BN2q1gSwC/aF5DwWIOLB4kvj/bA@LhKSeaKTutyBEdGoGM/KE7PB4wPUDzKiH4uQnb4jyo@mJ5kyW4oRxvFhcj4ON4kY7sf9v@QvyOjBgiA5aI1IjHXemhG/EuH@N10ZHetufaG5gd7VT8PPZ6GICf0tm3L1gHB/rC941gG3B/y6gVC0XWUQJ7ZAgQfbmB@NjjHI/UH48Q0jn/kCHx7Ng5R0A4g/GV014RdIvIRpn1nU9xkxs8Wk1iGK9nmbTJabGpImQjzsvBrP@ueILJmO4zIgd0blmVpNoGN0yJlm40r88g9SZfHWbrJT/bd/YMMvY@VxyXJsZ/XxcLC724FQaL2@rvKTO/JevXqw611txcQb5lXbxCA7YVqd5I12pSU5YOBYXFsVVwfYz/GSKh5T3zqFoQwvnHIS7FjlmxVQ70W17BOZk@og8gkT4Q1YBgC326DxGk0V3xji3OD@AYHATvgLC9GKDXq4abCRaTbGpVfEyRxegBiV3YbCd4Awg0YCCpBsKo6tjtQkJkw2dPjpKXgDcxJM8iTWMHlgqHuQ@hi6hJq4VK6VwKavYHRyeipXuoguEMe5I4px8AXbtHsE5xAcesl8w4S28fanCiOB7mk0DX3EDLwCoEOXQTJ65y9khZx3A9WkHbdiUYe2PKhkR6ykCjkS9rYY4Sgdjt@JBMRlIwH@ctginu@wTWQXS6W9qZR8Yk/L1J4M3jEnN1FwO38yrImXc319n4a3xSOZ9KU1jafs@5i3x4Pu/wKyP7TzI5nE6dG@royYdKPQ3ddsY2U1lSuiraV1DGJD7C14iY5PY1eHfXzFKm4MwHHcTaur16rOMtiM7zR7AIDHzgCqFAj2LaXTU1zAcKbIMBvfHV1kX0@c6B9HmaY@GdLGcxNsbFHjyTTG5DE2OsElRhUkpggW44IaAakFP89xy7Np9lkRHC21MejQYIDnstwUeDpKiTUwgRKphBuR5/AswhOKjkVahn6Mnb/s3V@F@4lMjZ1DN68xd4FCKgWoFtD1y7z0JTc9jhwI5lvRgQGbr2rAiLDM6sIY5bMEAI1jWJjD2XzekxbPXZCWuXuAszaUId9c7MZgFfviuscH95QsM9@eEhAJeN8UMiZdgZVMujMjoSq@LNf1rId4LM0ahbl7PEXER71ljxzu/oU2332yRneCMbrJk8gZKbm76uUSu3cBcQ8Iaji4syQecncOoIZp4drMeEcKkF5yrbDH0PoKkPkKJDUcshmOS75q8A3eNT7bJVSQ6Wi55q5hQXg5VXKpwd@t7bX/eDHrGW/NBar4Ir2p@44JdVpq8oUYWiURC0wTZcXBS/AIcQfHJYb4MOcHCpjkBjGbSJOmMW9ClReUz7mCsECdM05DSowNWQdn37n5FGMj4cUb3QP80uZUbFSWS94tz6ox6N2hMRLjSQb9GALfMxWkfSmAv8Kis3jmXu@GUYLEOgryAAkKDDp3w3Fq4y4VY/J9iXJu0vuzuIgHPWKW9@fuxbowEF/xHEwR@q/xYaL4XUuK8fxwyYAcsutI12Lj3DgRvVIPR@ZVeBgbgehgeB6pIqwOdIvJefKOfFF0R4lYpxECBudh6wquO9aRdmH3BjJWH5bBQKqPyjiHx@//QoWXdwu6QAbhiwwA43EEBAuVucouxROZQfQNo1GMB6NuMn7QL6KV7aaficfWI/w8vR///fiSPKJDfRirjyLuvhRIUR8tEwm87Sn3M9Wl4v0G9Z0p71R9Z@jh1fcBenj1naXnT6qvN2P8nioCQww90MZBk/05WNQA7QXyeYrnDANT4xFq88N06kEfX9MzlZretDCb2uz3TRsvBZ9fAp7nnEJQvC8c8nzO8yiCGwzkJJ8@kvMp6Hp4e74d4F3cMlFfDJMbX4bIxy/QJ3U@ty3GaApAzAWa0fe88Sk/ZBARQ4k/yBWJXv0wKy5TuToBatsV7S8uM19WJa/gVFFugzFK7NU@wrjXh8NXddq@CKVxkyChImxekgHqHZhuOgmGzU8iqC7k42QqpDqbm8ptREwtdle6mhCJHWmXW0ljrVvyrTXVSToDu/r0Cc@O9eZ7h1GXwXlj0ExvKOqO0mCK7bZptm2Db8Rmh2J2Co89gQrvdC1z0OkyvCgKdUCE5VvK2yZq96hdglaPb8Ac4F01RXdbXHhcfW/@OMlO@wyMfDo/jz33zSHbQMW/McK5ZD4XEPYNE2KH1cKCqzstjKe0F0jSe8A1PtHHZxzG2VOb@QqwifwARXiDM3GQ/RGx05yM3UEsLnsaiKQ4jtrrO6hZa7wKWP1xsj4uw4wTogbg3vFFysqCBzq/sJyNfaWl0vmLuwesMq@0qbmFpGOo04VsqDjVl3qkcHwWcXruBoqDuWNpNtXfQft5ufLVa7D7v8KakKnLlTGCU8HIxc3RoOzg0bweXkGON2twTgULHFDumxbahqPYXMw3OB9HvUu5AduLTGWEiyZEcbpgz17jRqO5qWnFratAU9HRAUQEJSDViq@d4XoZvhINU78hc9RLzA1gm1Q5vHeWF8Ns4iqzm3iWEpbZVNWWjSqrgrxC5Qzj8QbRXd1VwpamdNBCBEvdFb1ucWg@mqzFrtbkpzI2DrEolvp5oFnc2MbSJKAtad8PsMJGV21eESy@BGiMPa4ZcSCb4cTNNrM/DxQLpxxMi0VDdkDIeD7SHImdONN6lBBQpQlg4rzyrBLiA0b1E6@CnGIrd74Op2pcmUebdfClFiFbvGpCzBkhbf1zPzhrkmAgr7wJGRiedXFCV7MJj8/8jrH2QEdZbPYTGIeScLKyfh8qlo3FMr/EcKKaPs8EEBesk7E@jGIbiuVhCNMwLkZiLmm@Dl6YgcasHgCOc2jPxvLR1yMakHKCbhPLO3QoaDx/AdE0fx5GfrNdmDbutbBUYUJgmlQkRpnMoqWheBarYRpxP2YONosY4BAs8tT2K/@/1H4MFSADZQ8IGDz@jjOMTQUnK6nowvqEnk61REYWVQE50BvojmKo5sDWR79rRggs0Jsuhe4MQSPyfhDeSXUczTBunSXxZQBsN3lA291wbwIa6iC803tFjJFOhKjBhuuZYpxlujgGY8fct9ngMlH4BOP2RBwOju6egKkYvDIBZ3pwm4BDZ7xifNsAiE46LmY4CUrnbrBTms6AhGjXxM0VuKd0gPNBuMfDwiNi1CQosLEuiNzsqxbPDLhtZA6YOz4Dv46v@gQBOb5rU4NMxdBH@FE2Y7WQ7/lAAngQtw8VbjnsqL40IH6h4ABOc0dQbnd4a6hijgIHN766he@xxBwoW3gibo2fgRtn@JNz46tw/097z7bcRnLds/AVraF2MSDuvEgUweFSEqldJpKoUJTXLgiLxWVAjgQCMGYgAkthK849lVSqHG/s2LGdysVOKnlNUnZclTzkff0P/gL/gXMu3T09gxmS0q7XldRqayVM9@nTt9Pd53SfC975YpWIO1augm4FYLEZt2SsZ29fl/J9Tgn6Mf0nYpnVXZeCZYKSuv34kkBaFYvXckqA9WqkaGF7DmpqbKGFBaxLAK17jesOvrWw1gbdneEsngGBuK1x5wS6BPPlIcEEYxqnrtelYQMZDq@9tStzXwB6jBuUYwZ6MDlto0uaHo2XNtOkdw@8JAcQO0Sdo5pD00uPdjgvD/T8DFU96f64m9Nri6siuQSFHwDU90h4gso20f2lHBj8DjWb9Oj0bPmJVyErOCz4XZeJ6KZE@qNfyFppKM/1WuRbqcUxVi/AmAsvz2ImYXjhFRgqTmfD8Qt@OcJrN9r5g5ZH9974FsgKy1hI3ejhI78f5vFLhrqcC8Oa0HrGg@WkFVx@yauoKYBNsc8GPWw4FQ4wv@HVQqVlrY1cYdqCLazDN1BlmYWaUVyWXy55Y9fEo95c@Q6RbYMqpumWHGvHXAo81/Iqk@3axv2e5K4itCEhJUUgtGo5Xr/LK0lVR5HQEBQ3nmUcanzeUWA1ae5UNFPmKP5zO9XwSVpxB9sVtRqZPhyHqSOsQysJdwxV3WVl3sD6ZJHhp5izjg7g8GbjRjsGX6fWxFTqd5Gl1ZQ1vK7F5G/BPa4jS3rt2ux1RofGQquJh3fyFlGzXAYkd2hlwBWmjZiUpzbGHi/9BFMVqeTJ4Q7geBcYTEGab8CneRnuBzn9XC8XqB@U/IBoxzjpi7z7AH0nrbtW3x9KV2Z0sHIhn94LX@8lRq1Arl6uu/akh03Bl34oExqoLFqnXO/pLYdUc/nBn0eKwEnvcII4eP3nDG1B5VCfrVYAikxW5Au/LFhXd@KIXqpR9@QdGfdALDdltbIPyoURdoIevA13NiRVvTt2j@GfQw9b1PWzyC/pl@9SZpcvEx8f7D862jtsHu59Ze/wyR6VJEV@bVA8GZXppsw/Q@feA4k360cc4mTeH3twjuOJQ3GWUAJ/0hkGgbgP4q4L4viLFpRsTdxM6pv7yoP0vKe@O97k8kfMzJPxPWka@x6aCE1QVQn6d8YCOD8P236OiR/OQHJIhVqvffRkwHGhMrhnwmbOObh/4kpqDynyLkFIywY8Uoa94Aw5QClNRN@Y4aTpd2E1uyWpY6ug8coh9JegHSIgAwD5qHU7K1F8b3OtwsC7wHMiG4lt5Ri9IHvfq4jHXO0uVSt2uV/IQ7b6w8FxRnpPMFpAnBscWgWMHr6phpiMgqAK1FtAT4E40twj7lAZ5YNytVQpf34uDcJH7N@Qt4I3MMl/QzvvRTv9xPhJSWb7KgaAwePMYzZ0kbBJiRZ0ydGaogZ1sYpWZEVvZk6ebk0u0a/@hi3IUwzIZevWvhij8c/XnvvKZtaf2cfCF2@Gk0jAEascRb6JKqbzz89g5/@K1cjrmYtcZkXxpelEsumEDKj2OsYT2eUsaR8j57F/wBf2eNWkr398pd0twxnFeDK1a0UUbXUEm6jSfBiPRmoiX02JPqJBH1Er/7Wpw6f3NcEWIOxustrxa/TaMI6IdLTyWprwOlDPJSruprb@PNJ@Va@pto8q7eMZ8p7hRRquOdncqIo07TavXomIGjhburCOL5G/1DDX5i3KqbxxGaeU0eXZoe7MuGRM/Z0vBRNK6yBvgYyRxeG1oiHmJLWaNokSrlKLKMRLOSqncM0Xxy@mth6OYHhZSk7EzEt82VZ7GccGA1HR2YC2B7n4HEVQhpexaSijU6PmIq0yudAWbEL0C/z/F2srTYJs4PGlkdVv0MjqS6uRL61GvrQauchqZOl6eeKPy21vUAbWrC@KZ8D9Z5ZgQe0eiPffu3Mkjt7bE/ef3vtt8bWDp@L9O48g5UA8fnr3wf49Af/vPXqyJ6iA/vMVd4wq9wKmftftuHQ7v1KprAnCvBCgfE08aZ2K94Yd9yUQz5bfOt054Y/SwA22udTeS3c8G/Jz0AiVWQJpNUF3RfzWpG6c0OK6DZR8iu@IypcntpG8efp8s0S2FxQOXRtw89se8SCkx0XPStpoA@CHkApoWvwkS7rT@LROTEu3JOTA6T@vPYLAFD58Iu482sVIn7v7R/sHj56I@weH8Pn4a@hmR@zuo9uYu08xiwAfHuzu39@/d4cSuAGVksC7NTJYv6gJJQSnUem86E0wPFgfpUL5FfHqvZTJDIbKKsIX2ckgdN/TBZLCd3d2dlojF@32jTuH734FuRr368KyMMil4VBdWiDcqKDRCNQmo2jX2Jk6spbFKm9IpzNxA7NrGboDot8FoZDn6J3Yc4V1D68R8UGa4mYzw6ZQQ0XXATeiUo5gHUERGLLZwhah3Iba6PZA1YYXqz31gUV3pGNWlCOXlJdWn5BicMb9QYfD6KoEoHvW6qZqgzED4IWQTGAAvIPBhKD1wt3HSxKxLiEmAQr@kHCTE56fju6fIdeIBq4y4S4HAtmQbeJ5oynFAEctb8DzGDFr4t2BYqRQEZ/g0UlOv6@uXEklDvh/@caGr7IAacEu2IOVrYSK8NkNqAH29pNWL/CF7eTwNhhEEHfgsabWcb8F4h7dC4/RYOklqhFQtRsO/tlWjuoVw0mBOJUI056JaDt0uV158LtXLQcl7y7UiHp71GlUmJLxny5twN2FBrwJGkBUNPcLdCs0CoixJTTDniRl2x8CRYLIJz6ORjUadicdN1JAyjr2c@@jj3JykAthEUPFh1qnNeww1AM@hJyhDypycwFCDGlKnuBrFM@hHe1B@DZ8isoQY2zgh2pwZW2m8KBqlJo4slLk51NqbbfIGO7SWoniWTdYb18j7TOKnr99NsujZ5I2islamvPRnzMqMaBnpzG6eekJVCyaBdQSDu6QCfeOj4Vfrn@w4Wzv3n1W/PjDQqNcPuZtodXlxwtWSuRnFhLJYXlo3UnSBlQrTSLN@JM2llb6jLxb4ipXyIBxOfGA@d5p1nQeX6supg8oXlY0nRJfvXK4VJHsTYiEMJJMuLsVRF1VWaAyDZGTCMK9ExqLnnVVSoFw6v16B@Pa4yzUYEQGuI@Qeo0ZVo30awxv1/igBztLRvJpPN0af07FIpcURX9scz7KH9h3nfx2rqygaDHp4bTVFl1QmKs52as5Ti@dVwvodi9GB/v31dFtXNg6Ph5eC9vuhdheq23FfDouPpYMXFdH@/EFaPlweyO00PdCOmI@JBexaUrXxFm4saRo/pIaP1yYO1p7gAbPXoyoqpEatU0GffQQZ/OlODSNCuRMNCFD9ORod@/wUFh7eMu2CWVh32sNOmRfitsg4r6uPB2xHTJtdiXNNOkwQZp5UilzNi@NVnvRYk4cvJStQvIgBTkeerPQUXtBMplK6wg@WYiFQMNr3hDVyEVbd672IL8uEc/rqAklwkkzOphJ7OYSHz7sZJ82mXDcCswb@y@8kWZm3Kl01kVX1eOZiUgxwngctI7x5Tt5/t5n/nhT1cMMlvv1CXUYlfA76C9fPIGKR/hSXIrO4AXToqaUdFaISpfU2JFZXpTD/uwEpWOxzyUvbGzrkjmWTWP@@IYRyY740x1855/JzM6pvO9UWzylbJkTmgsPPTt6BAGTCWKw2DGpAoo35vIIo9HQ56SjGXJzrd2g1tRVKymamcRdSwd6Czj49Zvx7SFeFey2F1ZV/Hyq4lMiUpMRd2uxBpUJmG@ur69ehjveC1W8@Flx8xkS3z@D09HLloHSn/mkKgSUu/@ooPJDArhg6ByQAru2WjCxgsDqJJwpkb7TYWS2D9pyNkZbPGjMwdOjAt4XxWvNiWmsbcnY@UQysRPIQh@MJaw7yqtmYfTnF1d3l4K6XVLf9devjxcbAuF9@PxXHCbzcDjCrRIY8XGTvaKCSL7po1ZcgCU4@KD29GvEwNxRcSzrHG9uh1@40Uaaa9wJhi9Qr19FzpSxzSx8hiqdtkbnr/CC6xVdmXIe2gTIsl5B7DxnHRWOrLnTHZISQU@HstzhVkbTYJt/2TSDb26i@iDlMYDxgOnoAcy@nRUg92zirYIKNZnNcxrwJzqpyElAqwHKHjp9mdPRLsEb9Wc6vczpXRcDz@nULYnlrKUjXma3JWQ8QmbWksB0V@v1Zk0adp39DmcDG6OT3pKNAdmyP9Sp1zkVdapUUl2WnYRJDU4CSUonLUkoPJi8wKQl33VfNGmSZbQ5QJgtiIHXb5Sk/tQ7tpQdc9KEI@CJhPLuoJuhSaGYpxqVOhJ20LWsJKH6jtcokQKl3IBQJgsnlhfSjhcWMIEh3Qh9yUTFxagB@LdshGyqSbxYc33nOVL42PU7E1fsTVHGV7ERFVWSY5AlsfdoVxzcF4cHj/eiqLHFTeRRqJRS2KNQzLJh1B21ZAsw4cNJcNLkRPUZzz1zOVeh4G8NNBiODSD@jOeqCghFA5elOH/VfSXqcHiP9KTY3VxDTrrqse5DqTOcDILzV9NXNL1T4PRKQALviHkJLwneWRgWuRIlh63Igd7iMCwk8pVN5VYhrIVSqJap9M0xlBbXsTWfm0tsGb1/wtTByqRNOgzICdsk7gRDZHk2ZXxLGI7OSRhwk96yHWHb8YbhoVQqLSTnxS0duNE1I@5GK7tiJfm0Sm6HlTCFaTwlH@OIhrXlRHcoXnmvVGXhoYJH/0Zc2tGjjb6b5TQaRwwtuwhMpWFk86uE0eduJvprYcHJGRTReKPydYMXBAZ5D3dzh2k8Akb0vQCmNwcFxgtoAY5WQQSQl8kCIJVfxNhMbmW49BKKJLc4XI@LzUmpJUSXUCS5lrDR0akI13psNjpD4M44IAn@aIIgaJyviTMHZLNQcdpiFfGCkhRJnGlynTb/k0uoQ23TDAH02FA/qw02vRFZs9iF8NERMVsgO28MCO5B5E4FjzUzvRpPN48ksW0Uj0MYjYoBA87YSXX5XLAnkUjSGVpq8bIioy0ZDRx5LXk0wpbTMECJhFJAi1FQXjUhLIAiCHFxeLIYoLwSo6D5ZFCD@AnexBprq7EaNWg@GdRYHwtYi0lYo6D5OOjCvkYbZXTsNUO7bF88ebkUPtZEZ1TlTt3OJOCTRjmtgDUUwPIwGS0J3fWOveAdETJa9KsE7UGiXduQHrFVGgj467c060MFFKttNkFWGyLE3cLgpbyEivk6ymTfQsZcM48ReA5xje/jBmidIMxpEOyBSTZEMRlSoFGnmGLFzKHhUtNA1MgYSVhi6Rw@58j91pfOWdzhyO9WwcrNLW5WLbKLQp9UspSPtrbUWJSCYdMTiX9qsvGEYzgSURylMOmCPxEck0Cn4hVHoT/s8GVnAXHVlLBWh3QUwOlhJ4YDX1MW@6IKAprG5e3AB5VFHNiEvLioUyYOJVQt4li@Mg4lsC3iKF69HSRPJfXlrSvjYEEwCUf5yjiQAhfH1Fo6BwRz/ttKIrXIeKBZlExtFdpR0tA4W5GvdrwvSlQVaC9IGCLw09hXUjskY27Set8Qg640Hih0LI6H7fFK2oajmHbuCl8wV7FkbmG9sHBLqXwDa6y8mrjhB104CEq9vl7fCYs/JqLHLkkkQrr3QCGm1DkZg4iEs1mS0odiQAgntL/ZRNWsZpNuhh4fHrx7eOdh89GdhyhELfEehdc3qC1D6jqV0grGs@fblibpFDkCVS2wGxnah408ap9Es0enCEWOxVJL5wbc3GIGCmty6L6oNHDPxH3IoqD1CzgRsqTvZmB6bGqD3tSt4ksrF0KaJ5jqlZTXtqElBMN0IltCMEZyxhC2uPyzAWuoPBs8CxiwLepsk@k3zPY@Q8Mlo6AQxZfPgq@44zbqkhS101KeRVTBR9mNnFOhyoW8QQ8xGBP4q3JZ3FVOcaX9WqvfQZe3kx45vj31@q3TdrdVGp2MMj3fke5p7GzPRyeXGVSm2j/aO3zSfIxxuvbukeUE/qlR3tH@w72Dp0eY8wSyVmXy3uHhwWGTFNQPnz4@Qo@hsSTLBJRYQjCZEAF6dPDenQcGDH9bspFsEOKDvAn/SFc@BeGNmlP6e0ZmHgVWhWhSEB4yU8GilFYQgXfqDicqeBv6n1AHfAEtT/BRBupSUY3JIY2N158yL/R1OjegqB3jySggUNKAt2MjkYuWYJhT/xgLkC8iH/h20qYv8Y0y5qEh33Bkx8qigQwWy0j7rp5PqwOXyZPZoGMrdNKRZ@HcHQAkvjZlJ0GvuJGd59Cr5IiUhuKFs2U4OcrkHDWbXFKOoNRKzxhBjMxr11pGGbwDFFmU0CSElilUgF8QayKf93LnGTNAlMyCXZXjR50Lw4Y@CiPj11wz5ojdmrKeL9SPBKJ/SQscTSP8@dh8lCICk@9TZMxRR8tzPWb0r@os3zDbenZsep8K7bpLqD1yDxp8J7DZ0Qv57AvpTj53yQY0MSM@49E8QC/fxmSHqUKmcT@owUAF45lgC0I/0MMFPW/g31Pp2rWDCjQ2EFzOhLUszmV3lGgk5AcMQGKetW1thm5s2CxBKw4zxJYJUU2C@MCEWEmCeGlCrCZBfPoJg3g9O59Xk7ctVtbXWZs5Mp8Jxf9NFy8WFeyWUoUOCwM@s7g6jRnJHuOQ0HkHzUHNMxuQmy27eWHLoqg//XfAbeKSpYpUCTf8gmZfgPnnv2dt8g3dFUbpr7mHxgaFzIl88mITZrwvvCdJXDVJ2pLGsf3kAmyWpWYxuex3Q4r4IIVoPv1pBCaZbL6t5l3o8VMvXNfCstXQqiGO4D8WETivg6DJ5dX6Im@jbMCL2SubGovqQYiAQVZNkJU4SFKVry6ssmLiqyZWWTVBKlep8tOfyTrl@ZUA8UMNQXutHMxE0P@KLDRSzYdCSaA@Q6JNzePw1TcV/DjaBrNYEvjjEDsVaVzc7p9/I97usGQi/O8nEicVMOlLTXviwP/DVXGspuL4kFEUi6njlmWIfD4V4tMfhe3g4Y0vs4sWyc//8PLSlfTSvxuWDo/5bXVwM9egkMW3QK0eFM2konWNjecPBkCnJLTGOEb1mjOWHJ7F0mAs2oGqzpYWZ9HsFZU9S8xe1dkx5HNmsBSXhP71iDHa4giDxBqFv8nKlxkulbntmFxbjjtkcrvMrEsDcxgbzeNIUxyD6dmOCRzLESFjEbXMzUlmb54hLriWKPz4rXHrZNDCAK3@cFCSEUC8YXnvdPjcw4NqXEY3F6Xnfpo09FlYa0JAcpyD4usdVKiApkqnIqz7zXI7ArY6ncnppI9vaI6Uq9AxUrmMLuNIEBxMTn2JE0/cuxOvDz1wkFMLWUQQ80bQSjqFgZW@UvWxqpOqXayyXGa98RK5oaMkaltn7I0CqsxZlAXQ5RMxqFCFt2XAKhYeDdTPCRG7onVkfx54A9c24DGKq1cwEsgvQt7hUjWijPiYGDgKqAHyaHIawXAuZ5x0YxzOKflo8WNXCis4ci7SjRi7GCFEW0d4vliRPujItQwikRZE4yiWlcJajkeJED0G8jyNQqwVVipY0QizyEUReYbWmuWtHrktIqNWwkHYNDTNAnCEIXo5rtsV6B1k6HY51i//9pO/s3Ln5bJKo5g63qAFMgNFJAmx4ufR8LH6NtCjfCJtFWO4/z7Ezai7bsc7bWGEmsBADcSVghkmEDGfA6Gh06phH/ab4bFt@IJRFSJhlct3dnfF0XuHB@@jNRRfIhAVxIojEWwKK8/DTiUj@VIxGEEkJSzCPJQVI5BqxCKU7hWC6R6Te52ebWhgwWh9849ptOguf4ia7rwuYwgx22KnPnhPiLq1Jlo9EYqCcR6@@UeMeThi7dlkxMORJQkTfo5cIH51FWkv9Ishkuv7xff/jKqTFiXA8@G9yqlZdRrTT7l1eSFLNFusNlJ7FamGBiEV8aVD9K0fEzKfg3SrjTBzzdwVNZLkbv/wrwThwMcHmD2jpIjgyV@K6NuMSL8e0Mil4iteiu87jK/r0SuAiag9i3bxIZyTpTEaDdlGcvmS4fvF92WLAd4L8M3kgjqWI83NJE7Gv5ozS2XldKTNr4E/dYZ/YCKVZq5pGPmgSsTzyc/CZWp2k10nM31fM1ZnrGmJHf7kP5Ooj3TMYfWgB3BGa05V4lpJafNf/KXGP81cm15CML/82@/9KOzjNLVn09T@fC9cTdPFXkzT2n4ttiV9FY8MKz9NnYqfRquJrNypY3ymIfhJ2rhPo4M9TVvyQPp60U8vWfZpSL6tkOgFP710yafh@o7ClbjY491KWe7T1GWusKcs9Bj@5ZRmwmL8F3MxTi@a@dQ1n04Wf0PIkeFD49GFaSmXJYdTIdZ2S1TpX/TMi/9ux1tj7n541RYyLg5wVIAOpaYI7SHUdMtc@efxmPJz5mvC1Kp0tqB6ZNRSlbWAaNLq@wlVOc7nVtcKDh2Iewm1bL9ZJZl5uTxw2eh@Muqi1EHvd6ckeYzp@Q@DByTvjN@guQRuG8QVtrYh9wR1anKDXnD8BfJBdORzSIka6AG6C@IG/bulu1uscgrJG9fiWPpDZomu0XU6ikKpgoiUJPLVRqJQwXJq4kL4J70DsXTVZukKB0v2kfzIhjmXbt7f@pHekfQoDaPYYyjzl@P8RzkNpGJEb@XksUPydOmonciXFqSiqeoISD26/9ncLWLVpfOSBlga5u/@iT7oXB91WbvQHzR5JY//GBwTByb1BDT2T/5JCOzccrhlpNb8p2rifd6h0irHk@wK9aRU8@M/sJC0kweJs2uXC1kSY6qMJfYfiadP9g7FwdOjx0@P8ELGdIyoZfB0QY/Fbt6XSYCNXhIsyLI1EPNXWJw18pi8vIKXX8lR9//8e9h9Rpt3rIplDNOF5X4QKVdV5S4YI5qKK4@QHJ@F8nxpAa3jumVvHWdDjhAI0PuDANer78IPCcYXE@zwWZ5tTP5sMm1K3bJixnOFqf88u2VcxqRfJuBRhxPgVAXOn1P5kjK@GMqgK6sZvt45Sa95jB96oVx@EugXTUGRm83kC9@zs7NSD8NTTcZeyfXRPZGPjuHKo2NgFgZDutREt9lAeF4HZFt0XjjpvAh/FTutwcuWjwoy70xRJdq5/faM/82k3RGPjk85FMeb3hMLQbe9hVmhUwBkhXbnRaF31q3JDDYM1gonnIjcz1h9nPrqlzfqaYhhgPfsOqvdf9EZ9onbtdp9OMissGruoYKcqU/5PfLYMEZdIs@k91NBTLPNihQCHw0oB34CV6Wsi71pfdaIFJ/q4hFtFp8jYl6IlBWCMZ/1OChswJTzp2Glqtr6VDqL1yZk@PqASiEKEtHMFEzEIhxzpqwUv40vVJiGkLNIGlr@dBwqrcabv2AeHUUYQBMjGHDXLtc/eFZ/1hj47tlyI18@LqCjI4RuS7NGGlPy2cO/cfT7L/ujoR9JGrh@wAouFZXUOZHUwLTCii9yrGIaN9AsrXDjhYOG2oEOZeIWfSewPWmmSto4J/S8bdWtcIy5YXXZGBxpTykZyDR8eDJM7U1EDQMRpusuqUh8SbpQ1vtj9KelYIsw5ugAZjBDM0IM1BBdKjKGqZhHW4WvZZwAw84@cGNdUfkwFfVYltHNuZx/s/nXX7v5PVgXya0nguVNMaY0NnVhw3XlcmGPmNuOMa/QgvJyq48u/6y9AbmnUYqDudpyWZmmcD3YBRl01pj8jnQ8wS@pA6mFgnXNUPYVM4eXJa8LNaRa0yR8had8RQiyPG8gHEEkoZgri03NYiDp8sZBz2JJxc6MRk6pkVMuwtDTlEY2ZDEM5Gm6bWig07YWnEeAr8oavSQWCr/1EuNTsSui5bKuM9xziAqUhSFMKNJZp5FYe91otLFpxRAgIS4g6Lq91qQfbGbiG161qL/0HsVDqfYo/pJkwHsFEBhtwTVWKrM1kckXC7xK98jtJfyqZ6xqoVKo0n8V/t8qqET1f3UxsRKFrEYTK4XYf7@WxAaObLJYVK2s4Yac@dWSGM2Ck@FgJbMk9Jkt6MxGf4T8gvrc5/dhf@CNRm5AYY7EsTvAx20M/OoN8cYCnX9hXB34/cIl/yKbCrngp9jmc7@JiJoSUWk0E9aNHQvG/XQ0HAfio77XVr8xRvnNNfXlz3x0I@W7LvFAPjBB8pkb9X2PxrP94GCA9xJl9JgcDPl3uz9sl09BlHfH5MrRhzUPEN6wNJ4MyuRuyh108VmczBBaL6BpJ1AddK3bBLAmdsvOIeX5LrqntJ5Nez2LnLe4/e4TFxk3vD0SOpLKfpf4jpZ/YuG2tiQeARO2ye5WlA8T7aWLRtwVWfkYV@xzPGfSGMgakb5Q4x1jWZJmhoVK0fK9nlz/WSV6gIZSVo7YMjtHJ@IwCOGVKqcswIohkRLYRwzSx4wxnhVhjzBEqIuWJbIReSFkArUj/JSVhglUkTyfvQKwh9grZUXr2jCtzDNWN9G9J96VOdWc3ik8tJOqbmxibA7qCQ4oTpN8Gq5uYA45qPQFRpxj3zRmP/KObAkA8oRQIETgscfokaH9nJRI8bIODg@kv5LKw@uJNrpE61OMF7y/GrjHFCVFnLU9DgXT9XwCwJLl44@8kRyiQoRU25NjYLVpLVBkFc/3J@76rY01ahDFNVKg3WEnArpSBszoWrZMjTsJTvu6F7eDE9F3X7p99v/GzabYL7woic5suX3idfPNHJEODGWkpzAK9u0Cp@3u3X9w52hvtyCK1XUEZwNVDWsbg8vZeconAw5JRliEl2@pfXONidz2C9mdcjYnm75jDnvebLBCAHvWGOW4kZ11qJi8mWPEIDJ1ca8q6HiLOrYb6mrjcsOmTMYYtcBSg6tW/tKShSSNdS0hCUY2RyiTCw8N@IKNZwEoda@AEZC7WxOFMAwlRJRrbV0vFvWa2qRfRdhYi8VttjO37oEc/kJkDyeDyG6bpbXTElnY5NBbHm9t17O0L5Ssmjhxsm/52Rpy55pzemlPcucqxN@gh62weeCOhndnav7sidJagQHJ1auNXE4mZP/nv0Hsm4dmAX07yJ0jf/2Ro1zClnhT32MPmnaWb4Oh2EelwJ0G92hzDZygpgu0h91ZiUKSdu/B2du1PzLrGNm5c9Ju7jjOau4cqhyP0A5lBJuhewQYczVM60XSQpHj2bMBusVdRvnrqw8fvAdTfoj@pfyg/kFj@Ua5kM3CEU8aSA5G@hC7Bw8f403COFeiG4X74@GpHJdxS1dSwod9tBym1hcs7FoZVyHsnMduIHvv350dtY4ftU5BYm7BEEQvcFqm1g@GuUddfnOMHCs6uVbu/NghqJOx26sxJzT3nZf2ca4WwD8nZhXrUIWzskLYAyjkoAOB2Kh7Azit3zt6@MDJbrUEYnUSVkU239bEAYRCBGNjEgm0EdLBcLpIVQHbbRLBwJ981tqO9mWr3NrO1ubz1PY8GLa67PErGxJw154UJMWNncUprY1DKpiNXAcT@Gh7d@/IKkBZlH0xkWIczWjTYmfEjqqDyQ13CjoCZ08QxnHW3n6b0rDIxHeclUolh@ohc8BGPiAALS@scW0@bjldWw9ka@SV6OrcnXJdxJyslFbKrYF/BuxouXqzcnu18s5wjO8GXdfvvO3DFuK0MKSsF8zeRkN@Uic7HvZ7b/e8Pj5YXV9b3jjw7v7OV28/ublrd9q/BTyk9dwf4gP@eGQ2YNw6k9p/sMeOO0xd1IgB4Oy0yqPWi2F5rVvpbFQ2qre67q11d6OyutFZd1dvt2/fvt3prW20u7dvtW6td9pldBtNRUqnpDxoMfljtb2rVZvGmG2sVG73etXqzVvd9du92yuV1dW19sZ6t7K21tuotlZXb3ZXNtq32xdzbWF7MrDBqn0Xz474DvxWOnOXWdjbZenc/wI';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/160930?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16  "?63(o+?50;+'51;'  # #@ " /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( 9 '#CO"14"^ 9                                        7 222222222222222222222222                                                           ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>.]       )[-'][(7  >77*,68*,@'_         7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(#######??   #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'                      ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x#z#111#y#y#y#_#1111118&1& 1111/"78"oo@ 11     xxxxxxxxxxxx          /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@                 L               R.----._        #-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[af] xxxxxxxxxxxx\#184O@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~==RtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnqhqhqhqrqrqrbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTz xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #
#<<<#++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 4O6O@
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._ ++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<<._>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>][[
#{  
#=  
#*  
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
# 9 9999
#`<`(+?+?0l0v01k1kMoOMoOMoOMoOMOOx0l0ix0jor0h0h1d111 0eU0y0yx0moO1d0y0e0e00m1d0i0fx0g0n0n11yxMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOotMOo0moo0n0tx0t0moO0f0t0gOOM0g0f0h0j0j0i000x1k1x0vx0v0l11110000011100^_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}}__END__/
###<$+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#</++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWWwWWW\WWWWWwWWWWwWWWW/WW\WwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwW/WWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO dO MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) </>* * * * *[[3+4*7*@]]xxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#:1*23!/5x%6E0  !|*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****|!
#  
[mxf]-main=-[165]- ###jxf*#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs>>>
seeeemPaeue_ewuuweeee_eeeeeeCisajjapp_ppppxf⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡  
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡→ₔ₁₉₃  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  +------+
♈♉  |/0110@| 
♈ |/0011 | 
♉♈  |/0010 | 
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<]]>>>>>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./][[
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***************************************<>***********+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   + *
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o# +
   ++       +
 * *
  +*****
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x. -}
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>

Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #0,le._eString os4721en $91or 2570939597cr=B+R_u8"?!"3&&1ca g570rt Unuxf28t tce =1;#0:60Numurti4;prX of
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  x(a) #a
#define u8 "38\0"//"
char i=!"24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known;typedef int macro;int x=  !'(',y[1],z;macro m  (){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=1;puts(!m?"195":!a?(x?"196":"124"):sizeof' '-1?u8"67":*u8""?"37":x(0'0  0'0)[7]?"75":!"??-"[1]?"77":a-1?"79":"197" );}__attribute__((weak))int main(int WWW){known i;int t;f(x,x=sizeof i);z=1;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){z?0:puts("198");} //)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWW<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Applicative;z=ZipList;instance Monad ZipList where _>>=_=z[]--WW<<<<#<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};g=[here|here<-">"]--[|]
>x=1;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;f x=case x of{51->128;52->206;53->207};l a=length$show a;instance Num();b1206=f(l(toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-z[1];pure a  ));(!)=seq
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>        K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._#<!._++.-.>@ A=AgRA;       AC
#   /
 \?     -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
endif
#<<<#/<+>/>>>\
"""#";  print(85)
#<   ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#+</.---.>/
#endcOmment
#nocOmment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8      \    @,,1'1'<> @125iRE
#p|o51~nJ;#:p'34'3             \=# print(size([[1] [1]][1,:])[1]==1?17:isdefined(:super)?162:201)#s>say 27#>>>say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s9|#208
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//       $}<}}<}>}[<< }<<<<<}<<}<<<<}</<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<    }}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]~-<~-<~-<<<~-<<COprint("65")#`=>ass^_^_#
#9'>+/' 25       xpppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*^ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s* <e 5>1  *///\)Q222999686#
````

Pyret can be tested [online](https://code.pyret.org/editor).

Pyret has line comments starting with `#` and [block comments](https://www.pyret.org/docs/latest/s_comments.html) `#| ... |#`. Block comments nest.

Pyret block comment starts at line 16 and ends at line 214. The code is just number `208`.

Answer (score 3):

## 232. Haskell with RebindableSyntax, 10894 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2mVj/A39JArwNFIACUCBAggABNp@3eYfd5JDs2/cOyUYXgAJRzUIVuqpAAs3mjdGsY6xZKRza2bFiJHn3jmRrLXs3YhUOO0Ibq42NkL5uKPY3tD45FA7PP5DPOZn1woNk3xlJtkMggcrKPHky82TmyXNOvlqq0/vbv03ghx1ZxvjSsFzmao7LOrZ@rdk5tjVmT1XdKReXYzGE2rQvh33NdJ1qLMEUxkzthu2bbb0Dfsy1rjRTf6/ZEFZkbGBbl7baZ25PdeFFh1hsRzM@9D@4rG31@6rZcQBymbEjFQK7w/YVU1uOa6ttV7dMCCox9tI01H6rozKA0OyBrbmEvszYutYfuOMGvKww9tyyHQ1TbGuOYyHEahiiAhCqrVsHmy8@n8C0xtjnKmRmYGijieSVAnula3ZnIoaisC9P9/YmfYvse7Jlsj0sxkTQMntpO6qhTuIvsc2ha@27k/5ltnmpmSor5tZyxcnAFbZlq1NRVpmtqZ2ubmg53WwzmfU0Y6DZDH1Y17KhllzNqBQqheZmEDPXxriVIHACbd37MNW@dCDQutbAqUH9DXStw7q21Weq6dxASspaIYBHtGvMWF52J2hRLISqpaiEX4rhl@XwS4kpB83JJlAso@/m4f6k/worHkz6rUKO21fd6bopVtixNRhP@q6x5/rBrIa3XGC7feutvm11oMwTYeHiLBejHaAN9QNdi711ICsdjTmmPhhoLg@E2tZsCgbCM0M3r2K8vx3ZVmfY1s1LgNMgucHQpSp1Ym2I1mAD0Wtz6GAJagQcDLJwYvW1cBYd6K5Qac5Aa@tdvc3bhjZyNdOB6nZyTAfy3OiGwTqaAREC7O0scyw2dEJeLUPt5dq5GLYtTIX1rwyms/ZgwHgQFAOytFeoMA0Jxt5DuNFz2GjQZ47eh2C3bXW7msbea4MeRI91rBiDT3swUSz/bUkDGFPzSKMNoE8jaSwkNdDJo9CNrQJtbUfQwNX7QFndTTpMUx0d@RtEcTSzQ1Qd@JzPgrYcJhi71qHPQtGHNuF2NJt6DeGFHmZrgFL16zl1Y@suUBOpscmONNVmp7amSbyONaetDrCGw0lCYham4GJBclSp6@vJ3cO9JFQuj5FTB1CZ9vLp97@IqSxXZ0vNGnzr8Xgttvtih90unaObc1hoAAM7pUqs/g1z8ufnGnxHSit/ad/FAGsMqGKwvDVw86o8gAzKLmQwr6ITXfJ1MTcwQgmz9Ym6CDU5DtWB2gD@wb7MUsnaQ9vGsSAgqnoFhTYs8xLoCYW1hybSw2QrBaiCtgWDQJZp10A1YJ5UR9YNUfi0p0OlOVglIabEhyciKAxQ0IwFRb10HcsYEhzEdFxsy0AViIoY97vsS9ZVdQOjQDii4rm2NWdouBhnaHaw5vu6qXVyzMsG9Vgb2vE1JKcCUvKApt8P9UvKFABDRVhUVAz6@Dt/0Lm8BDyb7bZld0Rz/ZJ1rDYNpCplFoZChg3WMlWDsgVwWUydR4cErlVD7xCHUM2xSIIyQaneWEOjwyxI0L7RoZf2VODTGnSutqvxRm4NXchjlvXVK85NdN5yoeB9tQUVSwlQ2lRsmT3dhlpqa7EEtRm5P3S7FSYPdlnSyb9ObVRTG4vnGmROyknppXz@sgYNLpcmL3hL3tdyvtyMjDKOqzqW3okNxm7PMotMbrN4u24NNDOVjOBIZpN2KynlkMulpJpeb@e6utlJJdehLTYg4aRUa9fbZ3r1ojYRPZwkoLlBNNhdtVRbiseA5VCnuM73QRTJwXjwpSxcoTDLaSLJMTgX8kbCTPpdc48ECTrYLi1sIMCHco6haYNUIadIyCYQbma5MWBWSSdwiAJX9YtMMpHMhItOGKCkkYJiZz3VLWRbxqCHwyEQxXQGMBLY2HbbKrQeBwcEFwTALGtRu6ZRBDgL8cQbLQkCQAsYqdeOqEvyLofxZWSUAkPQhaI9WeuEOjIwAejLrjPFjQ0LBQvKEw4zwDpMTFS9hKqByLwgm7wgPCXyiRbpygSGgthaGqvILR06AXY34OmizYfKBuDLRQ4D2HgnCfGevjoGLG0@rAYdhuld6Et9YA/2mLU15DnAfDQ@oGAiQ@p/DkjJzOqyglwsl6N9bKqLuXZ@U/4BMOn3@Xt7EhY@3JmQ0bAuCOWGal4O1UvgF5YJUdR2Wxu4glFBSRwXWNHkeEOeshg8c04vtvR0Mm0aRDzRIkgDmTyvPTEUqshdhJAvgzyDUiPXHFhHt4EtGePJ1AHgeiLx@BsEiWTgTXxOFjwJABqZNtLaQxe4GjTgm57e7kGbxdyZnC/yQWgyefAKpw6cXe76SWNmlMaTYiyX970wG3NRyFij03hgcEVUjYgHVX7Y437MqtOfgdjyswgDQcg3l1dz0PYewNm3TGsGUiCkjxZBoiG8HkASO0GBEgYuT@yizupLmX4VQZ0B14CeD@2v57oDpwrjhO72hq0ctJT8qT3edw9NbCx51x7rrsXdLcNqAVt2oH/mvRTy7WFLH00UiPz8OnzrxK5BAOs6rA4j97shtLpUsusAwyT/bQQOBcWJcRMK/hsHQALKAaFSXYdY8R4wlZOx2U7FI40ynmVx7LtxCRwY0SfNFyi8RbP5Frwmc4lg4czk8giVd@w2OeSQTIroEZyyFVuIFO2ReYwtxOPw01UNR4OnOTQMfB2anMuluKwgsdvYwgKwthQlp/cHht7W3SYPZU@eCJmCLYJ6iGJTF2UmCeIsCD08BwwFYMTww6FzrnVCwm5KgoIs3EUS1mzbsnm6bs@2bhh5IFgsTNRtq4/cnb0igQslaNCIdRO1OzGW0lCqzhQh/DGV5OVkMvfW0s3UbXJxcTFZTTZgxFxc3ADXOro20JUB1wa5ZHIhXA5dFCNLLgw9oxjod5G8O/Mwj6QL7A4jHO3f64OUelatLl9k1TNFPIv4lIDOMGIAtIwPwJOU6nV0SlK8cQMFzbW60dJv46h30rb1gSDCF@q1yt8FFZaJDFBxlo2KQQ2Fl/tp0q/bIF2AMtDupezk@Vnh/OL89ryTOb9LZjG2VFPrLSgUpJfq5y5tawhiiHRWqsrKhSSdLYPw0aonC8l0KlWRDUhIlaTPKlJG5dROJTUYDVPn50kgqqDPWbtnE75RtihJPqkgHyjwgKydSuZuK5B@S7qQMkmIKyWzoLrVk0mgTBuJ4FChsS9FCHR4/D1OmO1MJkbd27Kv8Ds1nIJfDhTXaPSj4fv3yLs4jpbfwoyhyqW8gQDI75sebA4DJ5RXL6jVZchHKY094D3bJ1ErRf8KRkbWdgwUI2WbpwGv@TT37NDDl5arbJ@0DRNEJaASSEodX6s1LVPGXu0pJlY4IVLlEYL8UG7AMVGPwCDirj4C5Q549tgTYlH2Qjl22zJBzdJyr6hfxxmwJLRZaLmZkuwRFwlybSdoZyCzgnNgqG3gXFF053F2DgihL@Xzs0Ok2hTiSTGXNNKHyghCQVs1kX4dnTSuoe70kLwgFSM/s7tAVVS3QK7TiGr7rA3y2iVQWhvpLte/oK2eYJRnqpOSUOLf5BIzCuoo7WGmPPsNiWJWG3RVDaQ@DOWKP9s1r3XbMpHIuV1ADZ2qhnUwgXwWeaEZbW7uF3fm03cWcqDYlLcSom0Y6yRx206b5U3LsC4tlgYAbJq5HG/Y@ybauUBed9UBKBL6eyLQ5qVljifaoKb5hsOVZV9zUhEyT/C5t8DP2OxCBwBzynyy/4NdGFCVcqEA@ffeCvTxCxnCMllG9GyzAEBYvw1sN1iTP9AGvXHE/oftg1sAoD1ZGu@Y3CajgjAEuRI9/D1FDXdy7gP93AvqeK5ZZd8l6RbNUGENMVL6yLjLuw2UMDHhjb4eKSJIpyo8qF9kXOf5CN/ylV6527dcNf9lrucw/ImhrCfrLO7kk4vJvCzjb5yCWLHB8h3tOo9cKsA82tXaM3GPNK2dx1Bk08xzzCSPFziHNOfwMekHismfHg38mJPlv8xkmGzx3Plp80zDcHXaG2oxrd2zWPwchOVwyeIwtvRA65OB8iDKoITtRxMzITHXGoKC0tEMva@7@2S5NUyUwnPEvHPItUQo2pwDBEe6BqIlV52DMQetq8EAZF5y@GPg5IQVlNUcJ6mtdfLpANtzy7JBQ3KYQtpx0Sd9XwTkLWfQybkjQMBj7Y5QrnBiGj3Zi8Od3ebR5umzen7o2HlDbwGP6GjNPqhlBnSHOR/MG9q6dqHt6KbV16FEHsr3V8axZbl13kmuDPa4TwIjejgOdpoH@1vHm8dfi8whLkfvDw0V81hdmgDwcZwQzL1o2lbLMuRLczgXE0gTh1uHBx6WL14e7G82d3aPDk9DaN4ODV1VRvnB1eW8An2BIEzJFTjpD41O1K5PCldEHxbMBrWHGgMti8ky/MroxxNF/SKHASjs4fAoy2jPVNFia7OiUlhb67TUSkVb6bRLpdWu2u10SkWlUu5WysVyAX5WV9Y09oHAZVkbkQ0CXFy/R1MIpgGZp4eSK4ksFcpqS9FmZooH3ZMtrVNpV8plVWuV2m0VctVeWdZK3UJhraQVi1qpVeoqqlIs3pstnoonb4GK1wb5aTwzQ37oPXlql8vaamlNXWuvra2pxdXOslqsrGraymq3VChoK0qh26ooleV78xTKBgp6wVufLCvAA1AJp0BgxSl4RDonz7zTA3mlUywWV9rl7tpysVMulDqttUK50mkpq2prTSt0S8tKUem0i0rVi4uWSuBZPWg@ebSwgZrtBckKBEoxb2gPNzia@PMmgwX7W1pGhjfwJnNRIBcBJQwYiqlcNHkK/xX07@Pcba4du2y3kc3Sq@8pACsEiFO4Obvlea6hpz95G5nWBAYtuPas8PmRBOZbpXCHyG9w@jdUjltFIf9rt9uNeBfJ@0rGAdQIvJfJm0/@RqddRWGngmYC@/hKhI9PGs/ENxU0E9jHV@b4cLJ5NrqJkFmgPrIVQoaT0zNxTQTMAPQxrRKm8IR2EFahsHmz2SKtmcFzI/m41wg3zloHqGgOW3h5gEVeD4rRVJv9vh4Aez6hICYbMAwrK0Hksh/Zmohq6YG3D87JWjSaoOwMQ/3E8wkH@ZE4Bb0573CbLHIC2tZgHOpKt0Ve9r4u@miocS/zvkCzuKjy2JFA3vL57HbzLZ8haYrJbezpnHmcgsx8YIGmc6DjXEE3wk1ivtZ/Hot7pouo8SoIKQZTM0y@nj2nFA8j4oxSN68sUtZ9V7OQU8qIxUfRvzKmY3ZBKaSfCOhUpqZDuKTRb3XpZwYAikeT1kAKIFOrENJAKFLzx/RAo@usHETNx5HkW1p3CPpqvqWb6H4ATF6rEGS31dLngQIlcLGA95wBVmXHw9aYFXOlnOIZKHC6BsYzbvs93T8kwJZK6nZ0zoFFiO8ObRdiied//mEHKmG6inrqmLR239E0tRtqH925NSai4gv9zK7dQD4jwpDrIZRtFad5VcN3zEZNtS/LPdXuo3IsqhsaKP5AS7inrfGc25ox7Gjec3YiVUZEjs5tMFPvs/YMaIKdmIbhiZE5xLDUDpGBGy10jSLZWNm8GrQRV99DoimwmHkJzZgtYcHyBLc3dIf8F1ckPFSN@gC/93XRZSH3gR6jtnTtnvq21athx5JBHKfSYp5WZsAGBSfboNw11CvubKJzdsl52Wz98hLELPGcB3bTAwWULAf5G3o81CQcc@gM5BbUkwt9ht6oF/TvScE2@O88EF0s7vMd86mmG/TziPr22xW1FJB0idC4@kgOEU2fILOhtsZoT@l9egPDBEkeBHZTb2cyhWUcQf2p5mCd02AwPz4OuxR/bW12bL7uiZNklg6c5@udZG6vpjKLFVAPVCyMWXpfNeRiJ@Scy8w9S3XgmgFKxjW5bagONC1XVId2DdVHP/c1dxyU2qAb24HrnsYeZMdbcTBv8lpwLNGh25ahO9irjXnMc3K@L0gTV57RTxAV36YJ2yER0@nJvms2X7DaLs4cz2loj2BwfNIWp8VDLSdnzSNa27rB71ypomdda/x39hj3fmauHsGxZIOahN6eOZh02g@1VFx9RD@z6Xg1M19u25jpH@0Dnh0qrLc@sl07umE57IR@7yMLiNGOw39nt@gwBXXVlGn6KeyeHU1kasBywhQ@p15V49IyViqXeRV@5lb@0O7imCCej@V@PvdSlIe5lycaWaYinnPZ/lXevnqo7mj@yMY1AiHnPSPwLBYm5kDnFxCUCFz4M7twe4UKxczluXlhXgXY7d6NOvae32FkmUddb2QZjEnUBskPI6xVwOHaXPz@LqmV7k@t8zj2NIV29aFChCr3ytBgIKPfqSplxYLyiTGUQuHxzKprDLWhNpNXHbbearja@x4F5PGZKohiLAmTNBrK0CDtQ70XquOjco1jOL7dy2BUQ4dO/qCkM5PfDUA8H6C2fQSOI3RMR7w0h4NI5UYUOPP4fsr1Bl7PtjqRTGLIp3KkysPyVETadzT63qtXcT0QJyDry4VCQcg3oUmGyMt9@tayH/etzn8jCZNPkHLESjIDZ2BRhqrWrxwZbbuP40bFeco/Aa@t5U3d1Nwx/s6rglnctWVZxqdUGTDZjo7yGkihOBv3UNVNyUJisRkLzBwOGkla3XkGDj4ACUUUqIc69n21H7ZAP6paZVxHAL3ycuL1fpNPyJ79UCowrJMdCRd0Cfc8hZ2MJ0quklu9twdy8dVqaYbKH6OV0n341nLL9@LzRRQhF9OEI05S8mnJYJo7McGnBmMglt4Bpaan9TV6vUcbUDtvh473mAs0svA7IzhHk8Dz4g10YAwm/kamQEOik2uZoIa5qn2poR5j4FIF4TuPGXuTDjOJu99XLzW@4@s@bhlYNXBlMtf@Auds@0aVL2prQzS@Huf@pgCd6UobO95zJsLn4zbU57D/sFVuot@3aR3UQx09l5851/KAbGj2rJ7Z03o2dQ7/bV73gBbp8r169xUC8t9TnStcik08KlADe06YuoZlGI@hLvJIzjEtqzszX7u4jaoDUT8J71htQYB4PGjxg/GdiEQD/by@09OGMEw5lmsNNJne5oEaaCDiv/M4qTf/9V0tT/daBYAi3vO74n9QH71ULXcwoEdzYAwd@qGoMu1@m1WVe5TMY1qF7vL1YLztapdWq93TH8pSS1NdU7/Ke1Yg/nqvNjsIUUFn8g565wwdiGePc9ga6uHwE3zsz6vS0AzPzNJvD217/DCHiC5r8W22fKoBHfPSF1OnM4JJHsAFj97CvnvmO8RM69zmRWI3itiyVgCRRZlrQ4qsHxVsjKb85khEE@WmzISm2T7F@ClWoZAZUA/ZaME/0mois/Ez6@yZ4HWgTqaeDS8d6eG22@uAzIU/MxFuXuLGV4e5lsUcw7oJ2a5hSFJN8Zg5QvvzkvdNp5TvnU/J5cVsqKwN55rIDH3g8F8md4szsUzPrk9DjWeryKKGOlqXT3mg6yEpr2/ZuD8JxAm5bWtOG83myIm57MS5jmldAkeWDRYAe7AzizA9oT9LTomOdvJXL7RLFde8Hui4/NVwpgdAwDw5t/8YxN8fqo7@/aHlajNxTs7xPwblc/VSbz@L1IKH0KOuWCDJH5FOgF7TFXHT0x3aJuI5Zncc3sxovn6GojZhmfe3K99vQQnJSGJVOZP3mbf63Hfg3ACGqzPTikqgYqp@Lq/TXbK6iufMcs5eD3Gf@eFm2B8MHfGYnTotTQqbn/tX5O/c6MAI5XfAd1lPNdzZJuqQ1RVkKzEYBs55EvcPdMO6ZD@oFBiIYsDgUACf07C2YGg@Ul3oAeaMxkrpP3IOFI0ass0L9w4agrbMZN3U3fsNOK6rgk7kPbFAXOzCTY35A/zNPf1UDPLpbKoc3MvxYVQftw3Qch6COvr6AQht@@Gh5YG5myqOl5Y5dGXcCn7fILFy7yBRZaPKSqgVsNT3d5@/lLzGcNlr86XGD4mWGuh3Q8cYB665SwdmtDHdBBlsPpudjuEpCjtaVx0a7jEtjn1EvM0B7r8irr5jzVJojsYwyHySVgTjxLC/o7VxQvFReXhhPQcZDUauAfDV/rGGCwEmWMn8yBj1wGqrBtCs86jkTgj9jGEh0KfVgdaCujcC12whbB7yHdVVZxGTjIPd4acYkB3daGn2WzT9hd3zZLbpHD3TRqR6zG9NXPCR3Xabi9lojot0opA2XmUnA4tvyr6nP2/CwPDJ5oAcLh6PDHUzFbHpEh5e81UkWofvAXRmkf5Ya1nGw1zG1PmyAdXWNSd/oJvDEfkxGSS12aoNX0VdyK2iQcPpQb@70UGT9hdX4wo0vlLbCTQEsabHvFYdmsyfrbtEFnI/fqlQT7XbFs6KCccnzomF9pbdr2oEK9X5ooMWNJwR8Di1PfQOKHggq0a/1aef2VmcrmuoRty/16LNqK46mqpqsTOBjgPxN447WbFnBvx0W@wwdXLe0TAJ2l9E@fVWurMEbm4foirlWnaOEVwqpWYykhTjkXBC@9IEMA@KDufAjfv83A@HwXDlEqzeZWdnbOl2VC1UlTtWZ/FqnF1ccKz4oW3ku6MBnaxxzKOfLakX9aWkLCeXkudmlRWSPrhmgEQ2E1yNwHZ1evD8BiRgpsp3kaHbK3GNH0zg9OjQj55qdgyNvTRp1gHGVptvr@dnN5ziwrm//JOOOAvlUoPC9nXQioAgeBSQ1dd61s0GT1ekDiONimepIA4QoA2@s1/e3mQg2bntHj8CxbphL/dOK@JgBXHuELwccY3YzwWvXDTI49Y6l1cez42/TUok7MfyCgVyxLBvQi/tuD0nx0502jU3tIOV5@IwKtO10eLWybJ91tFwoRJthiQjs2FZV7RBAnPyl3/Cj5OgLZFiq5qXPB0jE0oRdz4qdIZDu20NIdcekveabQmQFBIZxOkhTukwlLDIX8KNgnTOBbRI2TvlgZLhRz1sb54weZcl8Ugl3JVd07uppc3jz788K1zUv2H9vPaff5iXbgXh4p/JaytOPMs8kNodNqxwcBmCg9Akiy@N4jxBf7@oLqSDG14fQCKVNzLcMuq1McsaiF5DJ/XQwTR@axQbvlPopnr2jnvo0yE/1GC1GzrugTYmmSgb4Ok5pgMdDF4lQs17XX0pNeSzDPKJy8qQIB6ZoYKLHwtEOyjx6AKMsjRiH1gPGxkMNUq5AG@ckAaeltGvb3krWJfDK4vzO1prSEvsrou54nKdirPUrK83yAWjmIWn1py9Ph8VC/L5aHX3Iu94RD0/H31WKH4FVLdsiPUkjz1v98XO7VKuUfjwwVHHLB6/S9b4SmhgE0u3R/tHuyenm6cvT6AW7jz2s8f3ini8BlsRbUbrWQadBwR0wTHsE/iP/4a781NsSWXreFidJMXC24YIVNA6LseXuDPEmiKxH4g@K76jhcKnAQRP6@rMa1H7MJpjHUJjQ6ph4YcDPNWIibjiZBZqZTryeOxAPmFwvfkMXkqkirM6EEsGYj2SVGx@YTe432Mo9iCW@8m2MRMEKeand@aH8yLOJMHdr6XcAxgof/Vycyz3l5tg7ik3gPq@Xpy9zf2Dl8e70WjQxuhJXLe@Vhb75Thzxp7G1yZ4R9HQNnUREWdo6nEWpwj8VQxmQ9y42tLcGw2KJZhju88jUwul/MdjQcMEytTxOMeLGqdFKkU5QBmkhsWa2M7X1UehLHpjdAjdLS@izwT24j5qL@O5uMCcoHP5cvjxioFYBbm8rndETFzw66QTFn@yXo/DouEYPXR4n5szVPmjjsPgPzQqea7iBRsxMZwpF0xmRfgamnkJBfZgpRofo9gSJ0R8iec97ucXz4SDPHXeqmQcpRXQYuMZjNKGOsADqAT0C8vVquzd0KKt9h4z8eWLGzS9qfz4Q6ratoqloS38IJuCkuGNW4Rvf@@kjtIZF82Iv4fb3NDEgQqAQocR7uKePmhsfF8gP9aMk9wSJ2h5QyWpHI44MceXEhx2rTs6CMtUCV2UcQzglFgaUXA8zJMOWWCbhgMySQeGb5BQXBxqQTjJ0Y4cvi1HNlk8AW0y54uMWRaPIaxTnz5RCYbSG1AH2m945CWCI8xOCGdyfVGWgXKXoCOJ3T1VPMuSJkSqzLWHuOqmkZyK4mWhSi655/aNEOCMs@XOtfzH3/kDfp7cuQvunwj3qLAFb78l3rrg/m0vRFHg7Z/7b0V4@yl/e53HKps@REskLxT4uduXoF0@jU@VCXmCd34nlcWvbazpL/ePmAOyLK/LPqg@QTUhh8E2B@oqtL8@NIprqmME5ykEVRjgSZ19CU0E2hW0DxRvUKKh9DT7IoVHKVXzecw4mk9ztPJJG/GZSTpZ6d0QTxQEISy/Ul4pKXnIpHztIaQjMi5xDwZHKElV4Imxa31QfwNq4vr6Oos7bdXQ6is13jbyS@rr5fgbP6NLABvjisIZgzgQJYgBYQ0RLbWkZhQJo@JAllSSyNM6Fm9qIA2myAEgEnqb3qZ6EDctQSpox6Y2ckliGnsKEDBsk3aNavxcSQ@RDIg4bjz3brI7BpsrUOsPddBcuBrirxDsBMGq8VmN9ew1O3fPzQtx/iGDhveLGU3XBPc/m3EoIm9ZeGjI9Gl8qcmz9LA07OmJaaHpZA9yy1LFfHE5r6xIoRYaF6ggv9jVPwBK6NzALNqa/tYaOJvbu/tfHB6dTJ0qR5DJSbAkSzbWM@dyLnt24TuSfr6jRN3ay58839rzSBnOVWC@QIhg5dlkNmelNpnTOam/4vtYptOmgKmElMJjEdOSDnmPVmxOYw9C8yHAbb6MfirVlHR7d3ax3jg3E1PJf5h10mYil8bGBa5zh87ZTE5mE7Pon8F9imdwOzlvf6aCmzNx645rXQVbR4VHKICDe1iAA8RyeQ9qRov1MnDI7TPB6RFFfgi4Q6yP23Do/EM/RyHIU@@4cOxawbFd4ryqnur0DL0Vg7G7g2e48TM6vEMo/NM9cs7A0N2UFCPrRx0lIGBiKXFo@Kg6ytF8S4pO2yRcWXbfEVgePikGnQDwJY@GTo8dWQMWmJ52NM91DIII2xlyy7zGvhj2Aa5Lj2MNWawGookMkYFQST@rXKGGniVOwBpl8JQxSO8Mz8ESBc/1O@XUSMr1tFFHvwQGnpKy0NM/U0Ci8vfLYqHpVCwzCTyOU/hz3L4QJuknHYQ2CpCrZ2pONzvaKIXnoVQvQDRF/@TNq@ukFJ9qA3Qamzg8qzN5LJvXEVVX9IjgSLOJzra25ney6Ll5a2t4pgxu/YVqgRRPXPsAnDA@pbp9dcBSQzov0GE5Rq@p85SZdVxbYnKDH41gskyGFGp4UAAIzAjaJRc1HJbC43VT@TrUDvo6Zgcf7/UBO1NyuQtwUyISW0Jj2jYM5WiGkmKgIEGUKqGtY92yKuaIt94cb3kQB8NjdOwTw0PzZgTTMXc4eQX9FGhBpWaNJ6HjcoIeyKm6tlYVtRFlNWsMmsU0l8/lAe0MFuIJqEBfsZMTqIbHQAPUtq11dGALT7@nmaYGBII201dhDFaH0MhsKevdEpANjg2mFBI8i8/E1lDIaPQ44d3krYFzQkv5Gtllancwpr45x0G1K4bVcf6/zufytdvUklEf50HQkRqppV5dySynM5klM51aMnGof/IEzTl3SyBJNHOgHY0ASF4ypBq0Z5A86ktmbUldTy116sU0xYBX0M9uIcI3Tj53u6Te5ZeewEidBR@bd97UkkMn0hVyOeUO8oc9ZCmfhTZzi8ee0X0BmPySnslgHnJLTczAN/nzkwzx7POTPFmOakIQzV/2RXeb4Kp@TUxdkMAJKLxFRQNjLyJjF8t0mx5wcJjw8qywObIHT/h7uPOB0dIrzQlL/vFoyOMZi@B3STpiiZ//x48EBAKOUkBEfM2qkgTM5G//NqGssHhqaWNl2coky4Ua/Ci1Miuzz5bOi6UESzwFTT2fjtvx2/Md@Zpp3eLKO/lM7ebeXRxdHR19JZ2nWDKxffg6rpQAdJWt0fexn1VWnPNhn/ZJJNL5WCKfVp6s5vNv3rwBcRc@Z41cIwyVu5DO5OTFWWoVXhqrq@nsSiWdfZpsYk6kVLEonTCm63l2rg@cTge@Vo8u6kgl@IdtbGBa4IB/Jvz6oy73CzLDQYSvF9cLegjuWi0n2PmqqqYzpeJTs5YrFop/@WeLd9nbo@b6X/5GP68t4uMQHz@5e47uE6X82eLiZ1tbpVIWiMfdRz84@npzc7O0ky0fnZU3SnJhcf0v/uPiYrG4XswvXjiOcpE8u/oqXiyU4rm//KPk0dH3m46D9YefZaaAE38r8FVYucyu2Hv4XHUZ/pP7fSfkVtHd6r7HARKE5Toxm2SyvJw8eZ3E4r5PKIqSGNNfk8iwyJTGxup/@dnhu4SbaBTzr2x4uol3iZVKgjvBAW/L3tt1opFYR7CVu8Q4X6/Xwbn6X/4dxG98AXgwZLwOP42yh2tlnGjIdYryIdFYAYdSLEK6/@cPfxhLNEbYEBr7e6zYKKZ5W1EqT5Qnfh2dJ5RK6fApeHsf8h55H1J0FaV47tVnqLqxan3vHhQe6pVZIT@/3r2WkWCiNZDjsXCQ78Qufv7qf/@rn//Vz@jv5/T9D3gnxsri0zc7jGkwAuOnWn3qly7PVitxy4JeXoO3A9//OCfDJ9f03mv4KouSJSr1bJPnym/CiZBjgg7@LxMk8d8/ES6W8KZN5TN2EerW8QbyJ@/tucme849pwj98vVf0QQ9wmSzItEfbREBSP3E26edVhv/CPF7APgUulviG5WezskbIn4rAc02O56GSBWXD5rABn0X4o3/4@K/4u0g@wptApj@L7Lt/YomzxNnFxTMT/1rv8O/gPf69c/HvtI1/x@/w7/Q9/h27@Hfk4N/zFv6FeTk0WuAMmcwxiIyi0T7m8xK@uVxTvPmNNxFL/Fo/LMYS8kVGvrs7y70eZWo18Q9yVM1/ww93QY4u7mR5/XUjkzmjnJ01RBbX5WTJGrHkivX0osEzTr@55ut1SCCzfrZet7bpm2s24CNfvG6crUeREJ6LxtOnGeyzTwFBYwk6x/p6o8Hu1u8ad2frd3fr6/C/Tr934gm@d@tT//QIPnNggvALZJ/nZ/nGef68wT8X8J7LN9Anlz8HRwOeTQA8O4slbrGx1NnZBR0nVJfPlJXyhcyoR6QxrO0wVlXSxeV8efTZym4xlijG43kK@oDDEggXa7EEiuhrXFJfI483H7/9X/F7/vHbfwOvkDW8ZApDsTExEHGWNgpG4bqgXClX4NBZASTMXqGndJClFzRWGBfGrNC3lA64NPgrgEsvdFnhkhXMgqkoEAgOlxVcdHXhcQl/XcBiw59eKCDywjWDVAwcKOjcU3p@aErnsTMWf6OBaJJTkrlCMreSTOoX5ZXBu3g22Tw/S17UEnnn/DzPhTZWLNXovNu7O9Zs7r7YaTbz2I7Pn1uHwf/hYT/8eu9//9B6fmj1Lfg/PDx8DvWWeZqRn8Kn3sisi8dGolHbOK/K2Ay9BpnIr2@cN5ZldK9koI0V0S/ziZ8AIzwbi@cx0GhfvbqpvXqF/zfXtZsaOfxXcDRrPoAA4w7w5B6A4FWtRg50w@easNIbOm9enfsu7si/ugGvVwxkbP8/H3n7Nfzr/@/6f/6Spc4uJOgGt3frKfpI@CdJt3e3d@K3IaVS4iW1Dn/oAe8Y5faugU4CugXXWUq6kO7uuB/8pqR1jrCBaaw3KHIACH0@wVM9T4KYAVphSsxmnZ@PCgWp1gIf366tfqCJEalGS0aWWjiZBZqQkpYIpFyq1UrCvVqp1SrCrays1GppH6oAL8IJQJqjtmvYm2qJgYR54H0sVUCDGZ2OnkyJo/Q3BgPQapW1wocPvlez2dHtZhP9lz98OIfumsQVI/W1MvgUKh8@QB9PSqDxvrDEXOUa6K9Kvhig76mO6rp26r0@yJ4nca2hc56U6NDXQgGBMT4rr6@vlBqNlRK4VyqSVIsv8eUmqcvMmiLdLeXjvBigiyYTIkiprErke5fEcJZYZxsNaO4OftjtXYKozUplKdUaa5LvoaytcR9WWklVMmvir74osUaaib@zs7PlTCm9mn56cXExin6QH9Vu1bpyV79Vq2gluau1xeHhuF5cffJkeQ2IUynUzmPN5s7m6WYTb9DC6V/kyuhJnC2GU3sDO3lGJq3y2sUZFufiPJms1p7y2q2UWSJZE3ByEpgkq6xRqROgN@td3CgyIqwT33RiwJTV5UQ6NqBVOKsF1sGJTJtZ3e4ieELNsBbOOTuaYXiHrd9YttG50TvaYixxdLC5vXuaLa7DMFXc29zOFk9ebiUUfC0H7xS8jO/Hu5s7hy8hwtHB7ubJ7uf7X@6@PAJ/J/b2vappqjbUtJvmcHjzDs/j1praAHyDT1Nr64769q06oA@rcZaGn4@/@PHHX/w3H//wpx//8Mcf//Dnv/z25z@G75/A96f8@dN/u1bG319@@8//@OO/@kPw/A/w/ffw/bNffvt7P@Rfev9z@P6nkN@fi28Ijn9ZopHGDzSESrGSScOgkV5bg8ZAvusxSOq3fvntz/7ol9/@9u/D91@K7@9Pf3/nz2Z/f/6j@V@M97M/vh/mp/8Ovv8Lx@XB/vRfcT98TsH/Kw7327//8Xf/N/7/F@IPnX/48Xf/HH/Ey3/3@3/xnz7@xv9RLFb@4l9//PFPP/7oZx9/9Bsff/STjz/6p8WPv/evlUL454@hyf3Nn/4C/3/2p3/z73@B///z//g3f/rf/81v/U/k@APu@L/@5b/lv3/9Gz/@6x/9i7/@jW/n/P743t9vH@H/7d@Bz@Pz@Rg8jynXp/p8@53y86tQI0gF2gCdYs6KIMNtjTVQrWMFVhA/0GF@/s8@/t5vQjv8XYCEt/8W3uCfv0DQT@jlq68iYRlSwOXMV1@BNPuV0Gy@CgP9hLEPeRA3C08/AMBXFMo/zIeCRP8HhAIwJqA8sEjiBILL/bj3L7/9F3@E/n5M9P3NML6C5xuCXULgD14Rf4Idzy9GGPYn2HU//uKHH//on378xR98/MVvId@WS2vZzaysPGD1A8DyI@AQcOUxcACooF4D6udirAiOxXW0UsWUzJs3UAmL4Kozlo6Vl@EtpjTIraAbIoKymubGoQyaheA7ipXW4A3NRRkYMDM8KANBWxm8tjUTG9UhjEDxvleGzkYFrUuo99YBL0bicbLNCojobLRFWCBmPXPMmun6iEfMoEeDMDDMEHodx5ViPFOp70CC9dEOQ1yIPBN7A8839UalPmogum8oC4AjswVJAhReJ5sZNb6B9zrhBPjYaOcbyEqlnsk0KuBTp6JSatkmpamUqXBU9gyjcqM/Y7jkbuMpY5/FlUqcK@ZASiag8TcTQG@QfWoDws8zaVEc@vec9E1jfKinEdGH@/HwDfSm@AIA8MoyrtSCryxjbp5C8IijylCy8MhwDEC5jLDs@R4kTGRiGarfDL1A@pCHT/ms84EU0WFxlpaWwLXeiC/Hm4egGTH7quq4qo2TSSTYVVl8ZS2O3rjyhS/nWzoiBSq9k4ZfBf53F2kJK5Wklo4tJVGtTjIvJTmzbJWsBC@EV0J6S1MBMgTIPoMQ/D59Cm6gED0Dv1giiMdFd5o3BJm7xKRYiq5lkUh510BgYbHnzuWWNQLxOhuPZ5UVPh0gcd0@9rVVrda/UUqrMXjS@xBvhBF3k0Bt4Q2vOeyESPfGrcwtDegGQW4l1miIyU@mgA@rxRonu6cQ7fSQKcVCLtb4io1yZLK8Y1DtIKjfllaLpXKpXFxeWSmvFpXSylpppVxZBha3UigXi8paqbRWWVu9o3w@BS6RraZb5fXGP5n6/Ff/ZNZnti9@Yo2RLOeLlPm6Ul6tjeuQPHnFGmQB4ZrI@FbGtZexc1rrdYszzJCb2K2MLXsBPiy2EGML4AUf@S6GM0BMzNnvH9bE/CxeTsbnaONKGZqOFDuHpsOxiTpsNEDilvf3YoeHh7TakM8/ynon18vRDWKdoa3FisvUeXb2v9w/2T98kdvZPwEx@GtWXAYKD4dDNDoLq3lsEP7U4BvD1vEEON8ThTvLK4GzgM5T3MT6AjIPdW2yA1zh6Vrs1OIrCbe0dmxdbL9sxGii7Azq6CKGF@ac4ZLb2HreD5@Na7vHbyneti3QD747zJZqXvGgHZ1vvPODnql4qJ7T193eHIiXgz5updLsvzMMu/0WZBBt4hxgC35sw7JmAayyl0dzSvnc3xaPk860Lx7Aj/c/f3Yaep7ubm4/i62wrcMXOxOPsgAqs4PdvVP/dZWHelHLPoqvdw8OJl/FI4F9GhW9RVZezWaBZcMPPrP0oWdu6bUHouTuuZJkKQ8KujlkoJA2cZtFfUvvNCrLpdXy6kphTVkrQ3HH7GVCvdSWukx11Y0VOV@pdY8OgAjfZF4M@zVbg1aiDVCvbex@I68zGIMbsee48G1N4Rs4dCf2DDTLPl4pg9dHuTHcqdfBC1DRHtDCm0iHAzbXEx7ohU5bv@wBZ72xPIBYS1UZfD/1A/HDSiXQ6l4Pl6dBflMhxgxwnG3Vu6wQy5GxsrhWKVfWlouVbGWtUiorK@VyVilmldXK6lohqxSUirJSKa8p2UppbbkE7BZCy2ursQTwJ72bz8MQo8Tj9NTNNh6tvY5nlFu5XiOW4GYYxt6nVJAzJJZQE03fd8jiGkSM46U8jktre9N6PY631xfwbnhAq7I2S@ztbRf29uLxLXxBw@x2IR7v4Eu5UiisbsXjGoVsw7hQjMctHgeCAMzlL4XC1nY8PuQIcF9/PN7Dl90VFIDjcR1ftjf39jCdt/hSxPgAdsVD@IvhvawCmIkvy8skQcfj73x0ALfJEypRTnfxBdPEkD0esg1h8fjnXn4KBcBwzOE4hmdeWTc34/F9/rK5iSFfUMHLPKvfw5dN@sTjNrxAS4zHL8FxaWuaGY@3wIntMR5vg6s9VsEPDzPHDeCmq8bjY04gJFE8PiJotX0VB0lP@GMyz549U3tuR7vkn7HNn23IGoToo@HuXuvzz1uXly17vLn7@TGGfPHFM/XteGi3LlsiWqsJHwviQMhVfzz5gTzuN5uqMTPkexBiToQ0x00N89ZU30GexOcSE@k3v4CQLyBkNOPDscGnD6At/Gz14bmltijE@1AIPUetVryGDdUdDzQ0V2HHoWuSs321bVs1fB/VF5OpZHZ8tlK4qJE366ek20LtDkO7KbrYDHkik27HZ6N64QLE/9WitzsgFT8fFct6PLvY3wDuVl1UN5RiKTOqLqbfp86zTWmjqFSqeD6j1U2ypKxsrKy@Tg/j8Sr@bCyvVt@nCskCY/CTlc5WLzZWy9X4@caGHD9T4GU1o@aL1dVVqXYHhXdhLGoNXa3ZTLHUjaZeSRLmD4URyiha4aVbfhP0mIqn17qpUXZU5zlgY6k2qivAYt0hDEaFSaSpDu51H@JdPRzzJZBitFGoopkwFVfWKnHISD4vrSM3Qv4BzzdiLuDVqwlHxMk/OVaV@YVjSmVFyuEK86bVbdL1J@xNGBKl0Ve4EYQ2gXqLtkhcd6qxUxRZ6a5thudotPCKQ9o@DSoTP9CHcYuAsroWizWE3HbE7xCoiVfcFJ/bw1tZLTuHdzC6kRC@d9vzOhmDUNDP7R/mXpqO2vWRnGojN/dMw0VZbc9vm2/UzO2O8DZq3TJrt/Ir@Y42eePWTjwiQO8wtd4Al9pJUdpMlW6oVM1Go96s97X@wB2DZkByecOPCyMk22IcEjeJeOvkm/UtKGyhZuKROBq@Lo0So1ijgzv/t@pbt8NqFWDvalqdbpuNJ@K17oZZH1JpjjQbt3TsH8KgrOHeiXbvzfkuwm0DXW/v5IbNzJqfiX2HE8dfpU/5ucX8iIBmvXBXu6yfof8H/FmX4/ELUA4@XICEXi/Uxgm17gxb/IqoQgsUiZXaCPyU1VKtx1r11utRza4PQDSuGUApvq1midY3qjUC/2DAqNjMNeujoNCr9bNisZgtFtayRQWGQRgeARK@q/Begq8CXwhX4H25eLG4mDJSccbi2cKokFOyiqZkXWvXBBoXqlUkNdQRvcJTlTLFtJHqWExdl6nKoIfWMIfAIHpsoMMPaGDV6rGmGjyCxDLvNlYyKbkgyTgdUHsHebSXUp3clrRRqnVSW6wpgQcM6/AtspVSrVtPvZZqqUWp7mjvauFqT0lcgaFyDxaBwlyVWXKG/bPC4oqSvZWb8p2hOu6Sslqsng2XzmQFylj4cLke/0EjfgH0v4uB1hOeMgCBoQZ@XmfmIkYgJAR@A5QRDQ1qS1kr1gRIbCA4C1AxhbeW8lV/qWRytZhMSskaQC2CN3Eo6ZbYSBKYW/KJshEHISVeja8VITxgSFM54OraihJL3MU6ujNgpbVY4jZ2d3u3Hl5p9j02HqsZ2Xt9wthlBtT9PM2C5poJtkguOdcgW8dmffPyeLMmoDe3ubIWWgcSY@dif6ScX/zUqdfMeuM1f57jogFIFQTUlmWcsQsx11xchjJ3Qu9QPuc2xonKJ9Pz65lG/jwWj2NXFRNoqUpZEnrlNwk6DZlt33oXS1efo1LKUmqVd8KzC@mbF7pxW1mWG3zxI0t8kwGS4EKjRv6bRAqY@R2RWizziSVMy1vxA8qjC7wNuH65HEdTgsYGJ2uvV19XXj9/efjycI89LVQr1UpY/j9/ms0qSSW5zp6CtKkf70JePzCrrHxjfkGLmhK1RHWQXC4llyPR6olRveSXUWk0ZGW9yDagcbIq8JiusiIXPjR4S2tQwEoRQj7@5u@XRusVeC@CMFcFKpYzxUZDSReZlPj47b/BvcvFVc@lrKwmLhI8idKqBG6a6CoqiUZeeCuripRwZP4GqZcTzodEsVBJbB@K@cv4ChAjsZaIJSrP33xgbB3Ulkbn8lIvkisfXWG0VAX9BVWYb9Cm8o28@Aa4guMs5XHBzRoCe9aBdKPRSNM6nGQjg/u4imUyQZ/d1S64no9aQNqkP81J45/22vdIOw68e2/wml7XWLmhMFAb8vmPv/l7xeLK//0ff@dc@tD80Pw@sMi1tbUVpZj42@lPPr0QY@mFTZbk5wPykRePCfb3uCUjl5eiWSu9IO@cHG5/b/cUh17NxPMw2PbhixwGnQy0drBJsW1oqm2M@d7A7hihcMQ@3T5ils1e7hxRnFe0PZV8yTolUlna71TFLWXZa6bklnEyt5wvlPJKmYGgVVitFleYCmzKweMohGsJozIq1rY1GHOVL7UtUeSFTYTBsAMd1HBHq7LPjw4oBrGB9MLO7vNDdvji4Ouc58v9T5/tn7CTw73TV5vHu1CO57snLL55wvZP4uzV/umzw5enbPPF1wyCjzdfnO7vniCCfAxZHIqjnGC@/sXWnbGTR1nVISUs4u1Y7SvNjfqr9kDN41nYUW8Tb9HS8NKZqP/Q1EHDC@t3J5sLXNxjiF7tdOwY7ovV22wBtbqFNEgKuC23V3BWWXn41fuCXV5k7dKL5CprF16Yy@urzCiIP2aU@svHbHFx8dyM@@NDuBi@ehn2wi0g4Bfkaf8HuwuplRJLgzpZLElByIvDo4WC97bw6vh0QfHDjncWiv7L/t7Csv@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@XDUiokGRPnlA@1uFtLUlJYLwMpchkBEEEgmBEPkTmZ22Rsist5NO0CwyXJ9FxxjiO8GOoW2P/KBbgrJMZnahVvxf61blggsJbm2DIIqjbwboG93KxCe/IHqElZ1kLukmWeYHKCgai2pdlWpZ1wXuCpzZ1E1quZgc80WsK0Bmp9l/s8Bri5w6RP/egEgPfq1KFAbN4gt2XGvrCQsvW1KuaBwX8kKCg3WKjSSEhONz98Y53KFqa9xdslhj7MTH396peO@KxoTmIlkZkxaMieFsRxSXPRgA0hV8gw/5bB/S8SXJkmYyA8FuZANuNwskyh7vz2uUDhdidLMXiJ5cC2fLcUuw@shi/WilgWAuaCJQCWHwK8GYAmn6itVmchQLGQkJBpfluKGAADdoS9PEIgkfEhyE3iC9/enwYpKuTXRn6LdQg5wo8SvS1HX3tRF@x@4KPytbXWbEEqkwLXcoKuPDIAFYBR4fzymjEbvSVrEJ1pnlxuj4H5ilAm0NWycGwAU4zY@QgOQfv11H7eONbnW3uNfdf7J5GQxFfzmmKjPdcyzQoDSkKJjKE4U4KXyQ/R6kuEoHLm6kjnkaW6Nk8OT3e3XyehfxJbD3oAZMyAPyInhApwZ2XAviaWhvG406WpU42WVpiTzBnWSZsCfjy6CQMy9EA1dwUO8NBkZIqcBD/PdqTEtgjYzOSiqdYSmIfzs9hSC2sMqU/@LDcXzZXlztsvLyKwi7H48sggst7DOYF75pc2EDIDj8RtTozsbeFAivZy8zVeiBxjwr2NH4q1x2ObTQsenu0BxYpZU6N4amIyFvEMTAwLkZFm/ulSBobsR2gL3Zj8MPhnAyJGZLPsXlSqCdg8bx0tE/Ny0MSbTQvMs/LOiU6nQehvcZOwwZjnB0U514MW4aOeijdqsz20Ww@9o5ByrK@BZWmo6ttDeiJ1iZhGoc3xzLgl87twplcOoJaGw0MS8cT5vC0G5xtt4OzYnOxQ5P1Qc8lwzE3Y@t4SJzYOU4H5PCz@Gjnamyh3Y7cpx26ZvsNaEkD81KG1t3VL5kst7uGeumAw@iQ603sxD8lBFMwdBUoSEkoB01VKZSFvk1H62Lm8KbqoxefMzynFHV7z4ikGro7piW6KGTRMl0Nj/J19GsN2A6ep6R1cjGuxj5KtQv7oVkq6ke7dycUXtVxNHtCqx3wiF7zyaef4vLnp@m8aDe4F7ep2i3dxdsimtxe3OQpeoL8IKpQ0eoN0epwxQZvdrTvnTv76gjfJmIhxcgyFsx/opIAKap9zVOh0ukBoSRhkvGXEOb0YD5uvX/560Idwd3RtQheC2g1BFpRL5tiRJ85pLn5QMB3iAPtfrV/2hSHbnG9KTIDNUeNDFG55r0NarwEofyLnE/rmsg2Ift4cgc/PBOKem3xthwnZQ51Pqht@A@pkHQtEmYdsQ1oiD0rXXC1qED6iEdwP84T3hKehHL1JCDoghgl/DbwyHhc6@Qg0@VFxF1b0wiAVFTPHD6hwfya296cmmkZqnmFrhrX/1nasduhyqLjhELlQD3QL4tQCvncI5Qbovq6fZDRuO1XCwEILd@r5pcmdmcyImIcXsN@0iiSYxriKJQ@ntLaTgXBaU@O4GWTvJQ4/ERSh8C1rS6aCyx7zBPCoxBStRqAoPBBPEEzPRU8VOp6QA1ER5JKKBfQbmueFy4V04J8Ztn9ueVJLVJzILFmdla5hINQZ362LnhS83kh0FsKFyYSNSCOJxeBE4Z2FyRxQ@uKFgfDGLURrnJPUYWLr34rYpxOZ4UL@Gcb4Zcqt0Zgh9LQBIQsRMJujAcoTGTOzzSCNvyug0kFTY8qCs1SWIU6tUWmg8SA/kzPZCL1FEJ@piPdFJYhaqdmhAIb8kskSC9oTzAk6ENtcPsC63KxlNM6NkEi0CDQQOPlGl791njkzXNDk/AvpsEGzlsm78uCoDXv3euEvptCAqL4XPVu2kBIk/yaa1s3A32kGSlgmE08TGzAwEvIYYMBdxCEL5OBN1Y25V3wq8XFFMQ6I7h85YI9YSllfT21KqfI67OKJPmdUUQvhqKHIgOTbjRYqphOLXuRSxgZUC5HEZRmIyhyBKV0SvEQFAUCpQwYuIhBSD4DlYxabRRxJYTYx3sRhcEjyWakni5mlIv19QoqriHPicjF2VlPL2eKEJmjXshEQzhaHhDyv4iWCJAvF0PjSAhFKbMMKHjSmWhAkOpEgJ9oOM3SxczB6dcmvHjGZ2/woeh4MrJmn1WwvNhSuaVtwMA9cG3hiadTDuiMysCPN@k0NnOQEahLQmo9DWeCsvyMUjFoAf1qE6NiyOJLEMgGiAgeHj3L3t431rU@fbBD4C6dL8PLDOpqllVADQGOAhyjApGBhRAN9Mtmuz/w4WAorkjcjMUHMErkhYVnTl@DdN8hsd9LidgYJx8eNwX4xBmRNIZw@qYgQvNgfwsfX@4eoxlg/8XnUIULWI4sC369Yi5yjH4Rt1WT33KguzpkAXgbV2hEWXlVRdNHTy99gc1DLuAnsfOIVDqEYDyykA6pXehuU7cENk5Krx1pLtGRjlH0ASpSDfQMdqMx1UByjPnx7xV@2iLN5FFsIhU4/Igig0ghpNnp8eaLk73D4@dEuaPm5sHRs03EDApmW7U7gH7QU7GDmKZm8EHVp2cMh99LvPEEy6S2vPPD@F0wCMsPluXEA8AmhTTJdzJHWF7e6KfgufesCMRRfGgQKpodbTADNyrkPpgojDMDIa9FnmsxFIo8zRoJacCbHgk9PtpATke0tDTHTLrQsF061M3k/CTv4dsCLZMOl6Wei3LUJbUXm5@muVykI/axHTnDAVrEtE48TH613dYcWlgWUB9QakaXEhGcJUQo8Jld@oB/cIO7P/YKHHTCMA26BV/uDcTcqLAI0iOn3XeScUMCEsfiyUi3nlhJYpFImZ/4HxEd9ajIOC8xntpbntpbSI0zXPZ2UiDTL87eRgSxWeTRPfK85bKxJ5lx8cS3j1HNdaHTOz1c7022EM51qMKwmmi1ozWO8LonXpU98Xpx0BNnC3f3C2WCsFGJTAw4wfgpFOZOB8iWmrJtkDmetK@hjfXPX0ztBl9opOSzN56KQfDUUpogTntwHvvEiaG5LQMxATekKYAzkdwFDSo@vpRAyGQvP1JI1qCpZWEV0E3gFsGMmygriZKWIxTFkCeyVTEK2x2vkxNkMJjZnclZKgRCXz6LGpha@dwkT6iCTjqduE6osYUEMisFcFlVliGCxO0aJNMAu8UyUPZ0d3YxKtPFEIXzZDKdm/WR1Qm3wlkBgn4AvQd8vcRrM8sdKoc3w4eRpVDBCjVhFvaWKbw8YsvK8nJoTcPhqxdsZSVY8oBbR1ipWAjWUeAmErayFvtOdrLAnsDbI3YcUaHYrLDNoOoOsqBmGNCJ@aOj49CPeeNq8Yg/xjVfuEpzDdYR7FgMDQ7r470nLQ3v98Arrl2mjJRcbAGY4mno5hhv8AbAy6Fqq6ar8YljZOSONbTbGiVIEenaJtvht8rQvSrA8ekGQGdoa9wADD4dq00XsyAOigc1PezTWt8sCgzXmo1rm3RXrF5aIJ4jmgNnDQ3eCDxPjzk0vLbBSShYAvVoNLJwMtKwjNTjphfhKpK4cnpQoFyeHig0pHlnsGMGiLyiqRCNuTu2IAg8NcyQPp4WZ4F6XdIHDlj/LNPg9CDDlVNPDxdo@BgzrfnrFzOMMdS62uExaIQU81BRmS4kb2KPOIA3r9P27BAciB6jCxqeCBfXRpGCeCuLzm3hjHgESRE0StGQYmOrU9tX3jYiCl7wb6Gg9lyH3ieBByUmZgH9OV8BgU1e4hBiwncSAvsnhxiFcUAueEdNi@WGBIE4/Ek8ZN/UQjwtHN2S0AsQAddrSezi@ecTbbNLIfooJcrn2SZzSkFSqC/PBuNFFmBYuhAYZIr4UdpfQ8nBXh4Fk3keIOWeDFL3ZT6S2mMzL5KbAopQ4pFZ9wlxJ2x1s5BC5L51zW@fEhNnnpgZqh8uJEElioZAbZb6vTBVCBp4XIHnrhWKwWVmL47HSShErGSYZjkCyneki94aB4@h@2bOYLHCrILyluwV1Ssm1SDdBGHoAxoao2UV3SJcVlmZLuxqqLDe0olIYUUkr5zTi9ZMcHTxri9aVIYDSlwsx4h/1smyzzo4GSJ8wmOUR41Z/C@6gCPUIV/Xgx7pl8/PK60E8F94XxVzh8jaw@0d4yHegtfJ8SoAGgIUBLfMmnflCY@1sCDEGRB6IvGKkjA7@83ZQ9HtAr/GxXC0Xfig6GEKWgxhqbNvOB4agujisBCwB/aB@DxmQPJh8TqUMGyoFQnOHOmkXuvAgExGjGf1iDU4WBUytyGGsQjeGVp3cW984inTuRhjGB8mZ@PwoojhPuj/tXBGxnMzguSgOSIx1vlzRnyd192vOjMayG4DIbmB3DUows87IYgJ@a1c8OSA1CCQF3ztgOsDYdlACNqeMIiGLbyfLzXg6z2yDFKfCx8sm3zHJ/jaPRtj0rLGcDRaPxdmSDyHxZBaNAgpMdPZpNohig54nUTzTRVJhhAfOy/Gk8EZIssXZZwG5M6MMlWqCDpGKzfIGlfjKxpJlMVTJ0hPDS9pxIpPY@FxyjLQswa44sFb7UAo9P7A0PhtgcpBc/NwP7g7UtydojkWejk5y77M3@hXep4Dxk7EWny8hx76Oa685yHN3ZcwlOEqejfHTjS@WEETdwS@IXVSG0pvMBIu6zcBuNsFidfEq3y8q6UEAicXziwEqw6/73RsWa0g9yresws6Kc9AlvLuQOYvgTDDFl300lZdRxtreYyYbxnw01dxy34eVPI8ljB/aGoHEPsEb2LMvVWv1dhOKGN0udJEqrSBJiaj7YhC8KJdvnoEbQguXZ/SsqBuoOdqtFJCKAm0E88yjTEzcV0Tv5Ce0YUC3g2SeAUhXqUjJnVoyQO/ubFUWFshZu@IEY7i4fidy0FYWYrxk@erTFxvWIPWjLoOjx5Z0zKxJoN3zOgiCq7nR/3auOPg4XUa/hKPfD4U1zIfs@5j1hoP2tQAZJ@38iOfR/PowMDrB29UOiyBbZdWCytVxu85pWaIvYXuhwgkdm00wPPbcWEAjuNeXEO71gy2jNX4pe4MAfDEHUKRYomBrV72VQ8wtVxlmExo4wHp15FlSkGQZRlRn66KA0agUdONUUwJsNEtc2JUQWIKbzEuaBJwLfjZYM2maVkDVgVHB693pMEAL@zwYuDp8mq2hRFUqZFqSRvwrMITsk6b8qEfY@ev@4vycT2RpbMz6OYXzJugiNdiVAro@nWe@5oXH0cOBAvN6MCAzWc1YERIs6ZQRrmVAKBxDEtxOIfbPWny3APpWPuHaLWhBKHHDlJ@CBaRb8KSanPXlKRZaE0JsARcRI8Nk9b15/OeZSS5iSfxey9bSR5KVqMUdwcmIj7qpX1yeOsXunz1yTptdGC0cZHIKWEPpMhKjd15gLgGBCUcXFkiJ72VAyhh2jg3E6xIAdLHPS3sPrShDCw/AEkVh80Mx6VQMShRmnS889etTAYrF94cFvjXCzWPGvziDr/@g8msJ7w2F6jgi3QNyK249zYVb/OJGJolERNMkbzi4CXaCLUOjksM8SneHsgj2hqENZGMplnfoMozym2uwCxQ5pRpSMmyEbtE6ztXn7JsLF7xKJAY3/NfyI7rSs0/GEAzh/1bVEayPMpwkEXgO6YBt6/F8FdodDZP3O/dMEoQW0dGTlfPkdeZ54@mjdtClil3NUq5TSdechYPcsR025@5FuvcRHzVM1BF6P@CDxPVzzrxLE8PpwzIoXiO4kU2SI0T0c/1aGxdpUbZMbAOlhrR6k7SOtAtjPP0Og4F0cJLMU8jGAzaYZsqzjs2kXYpb1sFa47qoCA1x3W04fFNDSjw8m5Bq2IRvsoAUJYREDRU5gm7FE5kBtY3ymQwHJS6aPhwUEUt24s/FY61R/h5/DD@u2DnD9GhOco2x5K3LgViNMdpIoG/POVuqriUvV@hvFP5nSjvFD388s6hh1/eaXp@p/L6FuOvqCAwxNADdRxU2TdAo8aLfzxPbqfYYOhZCEaona8nYw8HeM7cRGw6omc6tjUYWA4eFTE7BzzNGZmg8JA/pLnB06iCGxTkPDcfKZUCdD08cMWJ8S5uWygvpsiNBxDz8QvkSYPbtsUYTR6IeY0s@v6rPPEOCUhiKAl7eSzRLx8mxXkqFydAbLui9cV1Fkqq5mecCsp1MEaR/dJLjL@GcISKTssXITdeFCSUxGZFGaLcgfEmo6Df7CiC6oI/RmMh1dnMWF4lYmyxutKThIjtxPe5lhRI3fHQXFOTuDM015A84euxvr13lPEaOK8MsvQmM94oDarYPr8UfFtcnnskrFN4@y1d921bw8sew9XvKAPy@2kxQtdC6R6lS5Dq8dTpITSfTtVbFpcKiu/bj/Ps5YCBkr/v3cr@/Ihto@DfomvVuS0gFRomxAqrhQVPdloITNoLxOl94Atu6OMWhyB5qrNQBnawPUAWnqMlDpI/puY0I2FvEJMVXwKJq66LB5OgZC0ulsfiB9EGOA0TREQJwNu4QMLKgg86O7O8GYdyS7kLZ/cAmsqs3BZmZpL2JExmsqWhqa9wT@a4FXHSdgPZwdQxNzva30H9@any2WvQ@x9ompCo1yqz/Ip7UHJxcTQIO7g3v4@HqeONwLylggYOKF/g3b2GMc7OxHyD9jjqXeoN6F6kKiNcJiey0wN99hoXGs2MTTNuPRWqirYOICLIAYlW3l2JiIfu0mbPSR31I3MF2CFRDjfT8mxYbZxl9iJPUwJPUNQ6DoqsKrYVymcKtzeI7urNEnZ0vJsNS@6zXi87ZI8mbbGnt/mujO0jzIqtvRvqNle2MTc5qEta9wNNYbun4U2mAIunxwXYZd2UgWymK1td5rwbqjaaHCybZZJOTPB4PtIci5U4k3KUYFC1CDC1vPq0EBICRvET97dNNCvPXoemGo/n0WIdPLYo6YjDhITNCGkbtv2g1STHgF/5BhkYng3Oi4FChCekfmdZd2ggL7YGOQxDThgtbPgNBcvWYp3vzIoUM/QSAeKMNRoawiiWodg@hhQN42Ik5pzmYfC1KWhMag6wzKF9HStEX59oQMoI3SLTO7QpKLBfQDDZz1PY3hwPpotrLWxNqBAYpyBlKZFptDQUT2M1LVMOY@Zg04gBDsGkx9Zf/e@p/hgKQCbyHmAwgwFerurdcE5ZF9on9HQqJTZkURTgA/2h4aqmZg0dY/x33RBiC3RUs5CdwWtMr1@L16g4jmoY187yeMIJ288f0nI3XJuAijow7@JBFUPip4LVYMX1LTHOMkNsg3Gy3hloOE2UOsWwAxGGg6O3JmAiBEYnhpYeXCbg0h6vLF82AKyTtouZbo7ieQvs1LY7JCbas3BxBb/3NotLHfrARsCfqgQZNpYFkVsDzeaJQWsbW0Pmjc@uFdq/CAwy2ECoQ6Ji6CP8yJuxWNju@UACeBB3CBW/CTwUB9gvZBzAg/vn@fDW0oSNAgc3PrtF97hCCpQsPBG3zvfABQl@59T4LBzafDFJxD0Rr5CL09EwISsZX2efWhT6veQp@hPrn0hk9mxdHixvUGJtP84k0KqKabOcp8DqNVpokdLruFJjHXdYQL8E0DP9YrGOcy181QbZzrAWb6CBaKrd7kGRoL50bDCuTXTq6B0iG@hwaPb2z2dwGKDHc9wkLkCbw35LwztBiF7@Nk2a90AjOYCkAtQSpRxsvdSJw@kZaM/nuNST7Mcdye9bPCnSS1D5AUDfjoQjqMgT2S8FYfA9WNnkU6ebEq9oCikiWfD9THjKyoV3yMZUUPHCO47DV/mKtUmMyj0YpcB4NrElDA1ebmiJ041lX/GZIzS7Eed3VZ3s3jgXyBcsYyTPooeT/E4QxmcyPONccFYT9WccWHqq@7CR12tNLjBFg2/o4RunAgLzObxasGjZX41c4G0LWFibW6DyIghXRvG4fOaSM3a/8XhzrtyGyPcGFcJbtwSt6@GuwOtamDL5vjbb6ArpKtI2BKRoEQjt5RzN78Ik6aUhExqC4pnnOg5lPlP3wGpiu5Mc9rlD9Z/n0yOfaCua2Sh4vZG3j3qdt44gDX@RcDu0VDftbW/g68ki5KcT0Ov@qTTfjW7EMbg5tcZGYn0X7bQa8RVeCxP6N@MlPkORdGFh/CnUIVr4y8QDm3ycWrPoBqR3@IsBi7xtTGh5HmPs8q4/Y6uKWOTJz3CB4Z3hCTFi@wa8ho3hjiv50/WigzpuznGp7YRGeplzH2jfs/qdajgWDJJcUjPGotc7NF/4aTMxXg/kyYt@1xp2MSs40w9xgg0q07tTFrs@y6GluXzCn1OKwGnd4RBx8P4vhVYLeqeE8F0rAEVbVsQMv4h45tnEEb1YRt0VNjJeApZuimRFGUR@qBA04b0fHD1HWtXntnYJj2Mdc9Rxkigv@TPfudgONyYeHe6/ON09bh7vfrl7fLJLMWkhv7@heDjIk6XMucETC0yBN@mEz7rLxV7ZOozjOOLQ4XGogZ@0Lddle6DuaqCOX6kQUx1qsblz7sWD@WEvHc2u8vinXJinzfe00tjRcYvQEJcqQfluuALOp4dTjsQbP4yBuMMflX6UiL3D7mLIM4GZ8xDkn9iTWhYd1UoQYmcDDilW171BCVBoE9E5Zv@arpxYY@tBo8khOC/BPxABBQAIx1W34xzdPBHuq0B4DWROFCMxr/xwd9C9twvsiCe7Q8myHV4ulCFVwzIvY@L0hFAOSHKDQSuL91pUPRLTpiBIAtctQNchSvMS8QLlUT/IK7lC/td3pEEwif0PdFrBd9iS/x33eU/v0595KNysbfvewSYhGeduYg9d5Cy4mTvoZh9BF91QN5FQUST03baTz99NLtAv/wPvIJ@zgVzkrvT3s2n817uf@9HbrH/lMxb@/rfhzGzAkV05XvOducT07te3Yef/K7tGPm27yEO7KP5x68TsrRPilMhP2TyRTCdp9TFKHvuH3GCPpibf/ON4q7vFGW0TMpnHtSILbf1juaKL5oNDtsRK5Mctoo@soI8sK/87Ww4/v6wz9gIExZ297PgTSh3aHBEpaOGTVsL7p489sMQ9vFr/LpJ/L93wsn1c0m6PUfYMDGnY50R2o0ukidt8@MAiy8D5The@xpeav1hh7m9vEevew8Y4bzG6GDs8mxmPObH8nRsFZ8T2T650xcF//MzA6LmZorWG9yQKuEItsiBe6FGSh@tumn4Ty9YDCgbGUjpELGzEF3lNpZE2eLoejQ2490CarKMIysAYOw9ltGq8upiXmOhoU3tC/Bn4/7/stvKbIN/g8Y@brP4BN1n9466Rf9w18o@7Ru7bNZJYzA8dO9/SzTyIZgaTb0D6p1tFdg7Zq2ebp@z02S7be7n9Pfb14Uv2avPFKd71efRy62B/m8F398XJLvOvKKXPl5qNS@4ZVP2O1tbIOl8sFEqMME/dulBiJ2qfPbPa2jU0nnVH7T/t8ZecqbkNHmv3WrPHFp8OGuBiFlfsmiBbEZ9r8ixOuOO6BS25j/OI3lmemEc6zdPxrg2EzkZ3PPgbuPncHskgtI6LppX8TRsAb4EvoFH5lCytncapdRJaOjkmCOd/PpmCIBQ@P2GbL3bw@OKd/dP9wxcnbO/wGF6PvsZjdtjOPh4bs/USgwjw@eHO/t7@9iZ58AwUcgxta7Rh/b4s5BCcqNK@6g7bV7mBgVqheItc65GIxUzL2xXhsOTQDI7v6UCTwnl3ftgpGpygYS9tHn/@JUo12jsWj@PJvfy6U@QC3g6EpQJuGoHUxNUANYIh0VJWOEPqj9kSBtfoytUUubPMQy7RPLGusfg2mhFxQprfzEoCm4caEloE3IjKOwi2zt6CgJxKJrPrhLIBqZH1wEsNDatd7wWjPhUHs6IemfBOaXUIKZ44u2@2@dngnge0e76qm5J1bQ6ABiHhwQHQBoMernql7aORhJUFxNBFxR88VrjH2/5g7walRtzgKjy2UBKigyBCtUhVqrKWreomr8fItibOHVSnresUxSF4PCTHMDyTKy2JA/lfzLHhrCxAxoELdqFne0pFMO0GrQF4e0/tug5L1SW0BoMKopk6X6l1aaig7pFd2MYNS9e4jICSreA913Vxc1MgcNLpwp4K0xqzaD78eDti4NceGw9ibk2liOv2qNC4YErl0u6DGdiaysB3QQOI5DC/wGOFBi6/oBTRWF3RlFOOBS0SL3v6JgwPzbkzbGuRCELXSb3V37@XBJGzQZTQEh/Knb/C7u2wP8CJkBs8g4qOuQAlhlZK9nA2itdhKlqCYG64j4shbMzgm3ojklpYefBSFCtxRKIoz89JtaXSZrgHU6UWz9cG@@xr4J8ZRdPfDt@WR9MkLVSTfW3OwfOccREDnuxk4zEvXYYLi8Yu5QQlr2osFvCOb5iTP3tdqTd2ts7lb95kL/L5S84W1A6fvOCLEvk0C6nk0D38tZO0GtDraQJpzBm2MLa3npFzS@zlHjIQXHo6CN9PmzU/jJtVp/3xirpJf/L88OH/ae/JlttIknsWvqLV1AjdAtAgQFIiCTZFHZwdOSSRpijvRFAYLI4G2RKIhtENCRgKDq9vhx2OWO941jveI3zM2mG/2ht7RNgPfp/5h/2C/YNxHlXV1Y1ukLMzsU/GAwlUZWVmVWVlZdaR5XKpCt03IRGahGdWrN3KxokkWaYyTcMWCGLdCcxiZF2ZUiacSl/v4WMd2AsNaJEh6hE6XqPVls/XaNGucUMPNEtB2Gnc3Qq/LR9YEBJFH0vvj@oH1n23tGtXJRQNJtWcllTRZYm5Zota0UMlNF8toHu4HB3o76uj21zKHU8PXwrbw6XYvhRvlVI@Lp6WNFxXR/sHS9Dy5PYboYW6l/MR8yS5iE1JuhLO8o0VKfOXUPzWQt/R2AM0OPeOglGMVKM2GQ4wQpzFi@LAGhWwdTSxQfTs@OH@0ZFh0hub21AW9B4@9NgTahBxX5eRjvgeMik7RxlN8hMbTzJFPMWTJLtsMGc2Xo6qEDZIWbSHUhbxE@B9fypuR/DMQiYEXrxmhShbLsndhdRB4YlAPD/Bk1BG3GlaBQuZ1VzhyYeD7JOSidutzLZx@MofKWPGm4pgXbRUPZ7piKQhjNNB@xR3vrP775tsH29LOmxgeb8/oQrjIfwuxss3ngHhEe4UO8keXNItskvpzApJ6YpsO7qWl7Swv7pAqQcm5sIW1tS6MI4Fa2wf35BmDi1r4jSA@/wzkdk9F@udUsVTyo7eoXY86VnJKQiMTHCDjT1dKqB4cy6mMGoNNU@6yiDXx9oN4uZEctnEM0YCdyMf6B2w4Ddup9VDmhRo26WkKl8PKZ4lEpRkm2dWRmYC5tsbG2uX4U7XQhavfFXcPIek9Wd0Pnrd1lCGs5COCoHkPnpalvmxACxpOhe8wJ4lB0yqIJg6GXNKou40Gen8AS/8LDUwc/D8uIzrRWmqtjFN8ZaNnWckHTuBLNRBG8KqojxqFlp/vpwcKuRL6V3/8vR4sCEQrofPv@AHZ4@CEapKfDe8xVFRwSXfDvFUXIQl@KV1FemXI@wRpr0wYvf1pMm/eYcb70gzxb0oeIXn@l1RyglHA1BKJm5DOeft0cVbXOB6S0umnId3AkRZv2zsveQzKquc0gvoEAEFNRAMEJfJNFDzr1vqfiHkbePxwQK/8okA2gamqxqweLNogN@zjasKZZlW4jSwT1RShZPkU9cq/Ran470EfzSYqfQqp/e81z6GyRapOwLLm/ZIpe0KyAm0A575UhmmAKa1Wr8/a1Gzq@y7nA1mjEp6RzADvuUgUKnXORXPVMmkE1F2Eic1OQk8KZW0IqBwYvIjXZZCz3vVok42eFoAhMWyMfQHTUecn7prCd/RFlc4Iu5IKO8NewXqFBSxGJWcEvYwtKwQoZM9v@nQAUqhgNAnizuWB9KeHxfQgSEd9GtN/iKh4mLEAP4VTAhWdeFFyid7L1HCx17YnXiGegY@IZUUGGQF34cyDt41jg4O95OokeMW2ihUSh7YQxE8EYxRdeSQLUOHB5PorMWJ8mc6943HuRIF/1ZAw2CsAfHPdK4kQCiaOCyNi7e9t8YJTN4j1SlWz26KTpc1VnVwusFkGF28nb6l7p2CpeeACNw15g4uEtxdaBYxEoWFLcWB9uLa514L7cqWDKsQU6EUojIVsTkCceM6NebteUG@6iv1J3QdjExS0korYpQI1AQBmjzbY1wwCD1oju6ZAhnTXraLr3ymGMNJyXEWkkvGHdsWxT2pkhaJXZFIKY/IVkyEJUzhcUJIsWJqttELjLf@2/gddDmp4NS/mfZ2VGtj7GbRjdoUQ8MuAbPa1LJ5V0Krc6@Q/LYw4EQPxvfBCzEeMSCg9zRt7rKMJ8BIvhfAlHKQYDyAFuBoFCQAeZgsAFL5RYytbC7joZdRJJvjeDwuspNDJUaXUSSbSsx0sivisZ7qjW4A1hk/SIJfWuAIavNrZs@B2CwQzhusRrqgEEVyZ1pM0@J/dgYNqaYZAuSxKb/Wmk3xuq5ebCl8skV0DkTltQZBHUThVHBa09Nr6XR9SjJ2teJpCI2pFDDgTM1Ul/cFRxJJJL3Bm1o8rOjSFn9O0NYSUyOonKYGSiKUA1pJgvKoiWEBFEHIisOZRQPlkZgELWWDasJP8DrWFK/aaFSgpWxQbXwsYK1kYU2CltKgC3qNFGWy7ZVBe8ta3nl2jh2ro9NIeVOvO4l4ppFBK2AMRTA8dENLQPf8Uz@6a8SGFn1zgB8U2vVNERFbpoGDv3FHmT5UQJraOguCbIwQtYVmS/kZhHk5SjffYsNcGY8JeHydgeY3HfSEIPRuMDgCk2BEGhnCoZGzmDTF9KbhUtPIaNBlJMM0Vi7g5xyt35OVC3Z3HNp3NMumPTeZrUZCi0KdZLLwj3Z2ZFs4UdDyjcxPQzBPOIKRkcThxElLPgkck0il4hJHeRB0ebGzjLga0lk7gfSmeHQzjQN3UxbrIgsCmublfOCGyiKOEb0EvKxSOg7pVC3iuHVlHNJhW8RRuTof5E9l1eWdK@NgRzALR/XKOFACF9vUXLkABHP@a2aJWqI98FqUSG2XO0nRUDjbiV@ddF2kq2rgfUHCkICfpn5l8SEMc13WB5obdKX2QKdjsT0sn0fSLkzFpLlXeYG5hiXthfHCzi2l8gqsNvIaxo0w6sFE4PQHanxnDP6Ui55aJBEIad0DnRinezYGFwl70xHehzRACCfw32rh0axWi1aGDo8OvnF070nr6b0n6EStsI7C5Rs8LUPHdVaduglZvNrSojNFroFHLbAaBdLDWh7xJ9Ds0yxCL8diqZULDW5usgGFlFxaL3KG3hvjXchyaGcwjRMhHbU2A91jEQ9KqZuV16YdQ@ozmKyV8Nd2gROCYTkRnBCMllzQnC0u/2LIJ1ReDF9EDNgxTvhOZtjU@X2BF5e0goZRef0i@j1v3MGzJBUVtJR7EY/go@9GwanwyIVYQY8xaB34RbVq3JdBccX9tfagiyFvJ30KfHvuD9rnnV7bGZ2NCv3QFeFprGI/xCCXBTxM9eh4/@hZ6xDf6dp/QDcn8NOgvONHT/YPnh9jzjPIWhPJ@0dHB0ctOqB@9PzwGCOGppJMHVBgicFEQgLo6cF79x5rMPzbFEzyhZAQ/E34J0L5lA1/1JrS3xld8yjzUYgWPcJD11SwKKWVjcg/94KJfLwN40/ICb6MN09wUwZoyVeNKSCNhcufIi@OdTrXoIiP8WQUESidgLdSLWEnSzDMeXiKBSgWUQh2O52md3hFGfPwIl8wslJl8YIMFiuI@139kEYHDpNns2HXkuhEIM/yhTcESNxtKk6ifmWzOLcxquSIDg2lCxerMHNUKThqMbukaEFxKr2gPWKkL7s2CvLCO0DRjRLqhPhmChXgHcSGUSr59kVBfyBKZIFW5fejLgztDn0SRrxfc03rIw5ryud8gT4KiPombuAoGeGfh/qmFAmY2J@iyxwnePNctRn9l5XlFWZL9Y4V8uPz8l63g6dHHgDD9yKLA71QzL5Y7sR2l2CghRnpHk/mAXqxNyYqTARZxsOoAQ0VjWcG3yAMI9VcUPMm/p2K0K5dPEBjgcDZOqxpci6Ho8RLQmHEAOTmmbvmdhzGhq8lqIPDDLGjQ9SyID7QIepZEK91iLUsiM8@YhC/b5VKsvN2jfrGBp9mTvRnRvH/VMUrFQm7I49Cx4UBn15czsaMZJ9xCOiSi9dB9TkbkOuc3V7KWRL1Z/8FuHVcolSFiDDjS9hegvnzPzK3eYXuCq3091xDTUGhcSK2vPgKM64XPhAiLlkSd0nT2H62BJtpyl7MLvv9WCI@yBGaz36egMkWm49lvxuq/eQO17W4bC2@1ZBG8NNFBO6XQdDi8nJ8UbRRvsCL2fVthUXWIEbAIGs6SD0NkkXy7VKSqzq@WibJmg6yehWSn/1S0BTzVwbEjxQE6VrRmJmg/50YaHQ0HwplgYYMiXdqDuNd31zw0yQPerEs8MMYOxVpLuf782@n@Y5LZsL/caZwUgFdvmS3Zzb8P18Vx1oujm8xikolt92KDFEq5UJ89mnMBzdvepgtGySf/@nlpVfzS/9hXDqe5nflxM1Wg0SWVoHqeFAyk4qeKGzcf9AAKiWDG20aVWNOG3I4F4sLY8kK1FS2uHGWzK7L7Flm9prKTiGfs4ElrSSMr0eG0Q6/MEimUfydbvmywSUzd13darO5Qrq1y8a6uGAObaNsHHEVRzN6dlMOx62Ek7GIWuTawtibF8gKbmQ6P2F73D4btvGB1jAYOuIFED@o7p8HL32cqMZVDHPhvAzzvKGvYloTAvLjXHRf7@GBCmBVBBXhs9/styNgu9udnE8GuIfmCr8KAyNVqxgyjhzB4eQ8FDhxxr0/8QdQAxcttdhEBDdvBFzSLAym9JXIp0hnkV0kWa3yuXGHwtBREvHWHfujiIi5i74AhnwiAxVI@DsarDTh8YL6BSHiULSuqM9jf@hZGjy@4uqXtQSKi1ByuVSDJCPdJhqOMp4AeTo5T2C4ED1OZ2NcznFCvPFjrZbr2HIeyo0x9vCFEHU7wg@NuohBR6FlEIm4QTROYqmX121uJUJ0COJ5noRYL9dXkdAIsyhEEUWGVifL230KW0SXWgkHYVPQ1AtgEcboRbvurkLtIEPx5Zq//vFH/2jaF9WqTKM3dfxhG3wGepEkxoo/j4ND@VtDj/6JuKuYwv1PMW5G3fO6/nkbX6iJNNQgXDmYoQMR8wUIGgatCgagb4JTS4sFIwmiYFWr9x4@NI7fOzr4Jt6G4kUEkoJUcRSCbcMscbNTyUS@OBiMIEISFmGeCMIIJJlYhFK1QjBVYwqv07e0E1jQWt/5c2otWssP8KQ7j8sUQsw2OagPrhPi2VodreoIKcHYD9/5M8YcjPj0bDbiYGQKwYSvIw@EXy5FWgv1Yohser/6wV8ROXGjBGw@XFc510nnGf2UeyIWZElmK7Vmbq0SZKgRchFf2kTf/QkhC/mRbqkIC9d0raiQZFf7R39nEA7cfIDe00oaCTylSxF9zIjU7gG1XC6@yqX4vsf4ej7tAuiIOrNkFZ/APOmM8dKQpSVXL2m@X/1AcAzwfoR7Jkto3EqwW8jsjP/Qe5bKiu7I618Nf24P/1BHKq655mHkiSoTz0e/jIepXk0OnczyfU0bnSnWMiv80S@ypI/OmMPowQjgjFbvqsyxksPz3/ytwj8tXJteIjC//vEnn8Z1nObWbJpbn0/i0TRdrMU0j/drKZX0Pk4ZZmma2xU/T5JJjNypq/3MQ/CzvHafJht7mjfkQfTVoJ9eMuzzkHwskagBP710yOfh@p7ElTnY09XKGe7T3GEusecM9BT@WzlswmD8d30wTpf1fO6YzxeLfyDkaPDh5dGFbqlWhYWzSqbtjlGj/xiZF//vprnRtR8utcWGiwsWFaBDrykhewg13dFH/kX6Tfk52zVxak0EW5A10qjUBBVwTdqDMIOU635ttOrYdODuZVDZ/c2IFObV6tDjS/eTUQ@9Dtq/OyfPY0zbf/h4QLZm/Db1JVjb4K7wbRsKT3BCLDdpBydcEB9ERzGHpKuBEaB74G7Q/x1V3UqNU8jfuJbGMgjYJLpGy@noCuU6IsKTKNWamU4F@6mZA@FflQZi76rD3hU2lqgjxZGNcy5V3t/9VGkk1UpBEnsKZelynP8iuoGOGNFeOUXsEDZdPmo38Us5UslUOQXkTt3/pmuLFLl8W1IDy8P8/b9QE50X4lnWHtQHr7xSxH98HBMbJncG1PQnfyUEln0rVhm5lP9SdnzIGiqPOM5kV6CTQ@Ynf2KiaGc3Emc3LneyBMZcH8t49NR4/mz/yDh4fnz4/BgXZPTAiMoHz3f02O1mvUwObHKRYMGXbYCbX2d3Vstj8fLLfqluU/X/@hOsPqMtueaqqTXT0nI/TJSryXJL2oi64sotJNpnoTwvWgB3TFvU1nU3RQuBA/1oGOF4DT34IsB4YYIDPou5jcWfr0zrXrcgzHiu0PVfZ7W0xZj8xQSc6rAD3JqB/eeu/r9k/HYkg5asZrh752bt5jF@qIUM@Umgv20JSqxsNgpffLFijGbRWTCsF1YMtf5q0PorxgziVc6XIa/hhkN/NPIieorAOPWGuACNj7P5AVoVGKADY9/D91ce3QHelsgNXi5tvQxbiKglEDmjmWHe2DMLBf98FIwj48OB35Hf8R3R2@vyVzgLMdRD6HlZj1Efj2ePooMh2g5VjGoYBfxdf5cawy2F0OQA4QfOeDKsUkgIb9jDpWs6Kth@BaydATmoWq8FYC2slmXj7nHoYQgp88W03zfpgrU36D3zsHHRwjNUtPNHeJnPBObPTDxhtmI8DSJvm69Ey3vGKpIGtbhnFMWCWWXAby7Sqn5Re40DT6Xhe1O0e2LiwSWxpk7heUyHFomhlGnTEruF57T6QRDF8PK4hSjAmzeJElhHfEiHhRfj/sY1wme8PDz9KZgoGYZIID7in4JonECEiBvQOOX2GAeOulcDRuBMrP/XtjEEF9qzYK5vy/PHPp5lrm1uY/xsqgk2KHaTWL6tbWLOhB9cx1dh@P64Xo@SKzgBQO4QeqwIxgG@UB10XtJBDzSowcNG@XNkHpoQHQxbMqA47GhjqqfF33R8Dtfe80MCwJLV0w/9kWiickJUO5PT0OGxQNHP/TCceBt3NteJIXp7QIL2gm4CtF4FzBj@rUrMnUXnA1WLrehMvKlNMVrO5aPbFCkLBiXJGcZCaOO5PBDA2zaJDjRloqbQCtZWmdMe7r/7@N7x/sOyUaltIDhfIlGwlta4nF2ifDpkKcQIi/DwdTq311nIrbBc3KsWbcH6nt7sJZ1hiQDMrTHq2pFVdKmYsJ4ZMai1HuqqsnoTSb2/guepcLghK5MxRhY2ZePKkb@yYqJII60VFMGEXQdl7IK6egK/QPEsAOXqCmgBod1a6PJguH@SXHPneqWixtQ2fauAYq1UdvkumPkA5spXRvFoMkxo2yKNnbZRBCWHEW1YtV0vkl5wzIZx5hbfCYuNLsznykB4bU3sC/kMz7CPXFjccMfB/ZnsP2sid5agQeyTWtO2RULxf/@naDfm8dG9gRXZFzjFfejKsG0OK/V9jnJlFdljg2IfOhE4mg9IuUZu1FAFOkFv5tCzYb0HZ@BYWB/qNEaWfUEnkLquu2ZfAMnxCM@KjkAZeseA0W5gWj@RBj@gjcHGqL54McTQdbdwn@79J4/fgy4/whgQYXTyQfPWjWq5WARvgnYJXYzGbTw8eHKIs/3YdmjWfxema9Eu47Yi4uDiO97uIe7LJlatiqMQNOepF4nah/dnx@3Tp2COWcU2NEHSyGrrO3P4FC2et9PbyDWTnQs20qlLUGdjr9/gTed56L62Tu1GBP/OdBIbQMKt1wl7BIVcvOSXanV/CLP1e8dPHrvFnbaBWN2MUVEsdZRwgKCQwFiYRH54QnTwyTuUqojvVpDAwKdUNHeTddmptneLjfk8l5/HQbvHUTmKsQD3rElZSNzYXezSxjiWgtnIczGBp7Zv7B@bZSg7nng2JtI7BDNSWhww0JU0WNxQU9AUOHuGMK67fvMmpWGRSei69dVVG7dw5oCN7mkCWh5Y48Z83HZ7lmrI9sh3yL31pkyLjJO6U6@2h@EbbxxWa7frqxt37gZj9O17Xti9GYIKcdv47JsfzW7iZTva8j0NBv2bfX@Ai0rX129tHvj3f/f9rWe3H1rdzu/UzLL5MqR3eMcjnYFx@43YoQcdO@6ydBETQ8DZbVdH7VdBdb232t1c3azd6Xl3NrzN1bXN7oa3ttXZ2trq9tc3O72tO@07G91OFUM7UhHnnDb4TRZ/JNu/Gtk8w2yzvrrV79dqt@/0Nrb6W/XVtbX1zuZGb3V9vb9Za6@t3e7VNztbneVWW8xPARSs1Ls4d6Q18Dv5xl1hQbeL0vb/AQ';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63o+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D-v ef26q-[af.q]PkPPX)\( '#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_  7 )(22)S  ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### va5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@  111111111     xxxxxxxxx    /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  # >  #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# 36!@`D  e ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #
#comment -[ ]           ">r"{\        Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~ /                      >/          MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????!                                                           
#[#[]]HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb           #
#  ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
############################################################################## 
 #-]+-}}[.^x+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4ox '6o@]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
#= []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999
#   ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_)\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1*)echo 54;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo 166;;*1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||\'_\'[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and 9or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,\'iters\')and 200or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwwwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#cepp  
MsgBox (0,"",169     )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>  ;
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}  --[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>x--/2  
> =157;y=146--/2 
>main=print y{- 
  
\begin{code}  
{-x   ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
#     >>END-IF
OOO    program-id.h.procedure
231    DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
uuu # >>IF 2>2
ppppppppppppp;ppp
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
  
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         # $/&&1nu le._e lo=Bid>834757609195 Cry U#age$f ata?6-/8;fPLesc~+Num;reharepcons>E~-< =>+>
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*
#include<stdio.h>
#define  z(a,_ ) #a#_
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,... ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf ("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:!*z(\,_)?218:sizeof' '-1?67^*u"":*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0,)[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(int WWWW){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//)<*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import System.IO.Unsafe;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#";f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=7=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217,232]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h  (0::Real a=>a)) +q?6+(-0)- 45);q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);(!)=seq;instance Num()
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--}
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof(" (\");print'(''72'')';end!");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#    /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#";  print(85)
#     ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print  #~+ /.---.>/~#();}}
#endcomment
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#⟫say 27#⟫say 167#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#208#COprint ("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

This answer is based on [the answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171607) of Ørjan Johansen.

```haskell
b1206|let _._=x;negate _=7=[222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217,232]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h  (0::Real a=>a)) +q?6+(-0)- 45);
```

`-` before `45` is a binary operator and is not affected by `negate`. `-0` is not in front of `l(...)` because of DOBELA. Space before `+q?6` is for LMBM – see first `O` on line 2.

Test all GHC extensions [on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVRtb9s2EP7uX0Er/iAtpiC5rtOZkYK5SZEAbZMmGzbMc11aOr0AFKlQVCvD8W/PTs7LPFgVQEl3vIf33HMkV7zKHh8jbkhIEldkVQ@iTBEqieWP3k2JxYiuZZpFhEZleRBy4h2E0L8@Q8pN/h0@5gY0F9UhatSB@lLzKv9SKwMdgHEH4BNP8@gS@e@F72He/dqBmXGZ3nCDvORBlpH3tguRS67XPytl5E06MBeNARlDfA4Jr4W5rQV0IE86kL@VpcijnXrnqrOukddV1@e6OIcoL7oo@p09Up@UVIXSZZZXxS1URueRyZU8hPtd2iP4o4q4QHnijpRdDb7bpeguyh//FHDODd9PgMGoHKXUIkfkEpoPQnHz0p@9JUddHK6/g8Z47E27uEwPqb/pgt3CCuvkKwF3a2l484x6fAzzolTakBsNoo6BPZstZ/dDLSOjtPteycr8b@Yp94vrbl0ZKNyra/cPWfHkdZHfoTHuJWiIVfTiw7WMVsK9aCIo23axDf2TbnPMwGUEpO1LHhMehPjHY3uXm3DnR4brkGUYBsuggKI0a0rJKT698BWLe4jMyFNkolVxJQ2koMkymBE86Ey2xxpac9AcNb0wbhszC2abejrF2C2DALRW2jqyWHImg3pXzQ3oROni6nqQEPiGWzvKvv1z0ca950JstjTURLJXElfVkzjkJfuOz6bl8zyxDLwtS4N5639oX6fUshaUzh8WvbAJPLY@4kFVr4zmuNu8lY9nlDXow1uEZWQVrL42TAdlrYEJVEqATE02qDL1g3C2C38QYMjSXQbNf0WfBHPcUkM8fkM8UUO8HPF/guME7TEOHwfO@2i/GS36fVvYFiHW0Gs81x/64A@NupCosTedtlJjj3YmfrlzPPpF2LEi/JTuWjb3F6xlSPgwI2WOL2Ij7ha4eAI45Pj@bHJsU8@hZPzWYffIUQ/s2J05Z2MW2zOydNCREA/HiEzGLAnsrw6z@05QwT3bb7vt9MKC53JXd9lHhYMStTaDqi7mXn/iDzd0SbeCV2bQXt7zejCnPtboPaSn1t@htUD9t71/AQ).

Comment: That's some quick turnaround! Pesky DOBELA. It looks like you can combine it with the `q?6`, like ``b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h  (0::Real a=>a)) -(-q?6)- 44)``.

Comment: ...make that `-(-q?6+44)`.

Answer (score 3):

## 247. [Perl 5 (cperl)](http://perl11.org/cperl/), 11530 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWmp771zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@yFbemjTk9nAGG4Y9fwKfoCgyi6pxRm0afI2FPH9QxMvmt4noOOJcY2jNHYv2iApQwQums6T7aefXotcIWxT3XI2dgyptfyombZF6bh9q6FUFX2@fHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao69cD3d0q/Hn2dbE9/Z96@7F9jWwLB1pskVWbvuWWTbrn4jSIm5ht7rm5Yhm3aXSWxoWGPDZejC@o4LTeYbVjlbzra3ZiHlLoYtzzyvRVsPL6a7Aw88nTMDjAa0xNg0eqzvOiOm2945pKRWsjN4jLayiA5dyCAgGnvtQeiewTzbHI8Nn3tCcQ2XvCFlZpn2aYxj36Hr9CZd0x4AnAH1Op74VCYv1oVgDTYOcFhGA4tTLXAwyMKRMzLm28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAWaxdzPMc9jEm3PqWPpQ7soxrFxMhY1OLWay7njMuBcUA7K0ly0zY@S8Ntlb8LeGHpuOR8wzR@Dtd51@3zDYW2M8hOCxnhNjcHXH14oV2RIGwNgGFG3n8NtQaT7Wpd2HfPVYZw4OMkEZpuLqtgN15zJbH3FU6I4vqOgQTRSi7zgyuvccw7OTPjt33FPWMbo6lhkT84xBX59YkKLZx7YAJDA9NnLgDS1oM8gWBPaxIjBuTCy2tCCYTNi2xhh6Jbatg7gCDR028bmrA3K4XtCIvjkC1DD9pMcM3TORXEEQz7B7hBbjiJA5UNr5FmdnJvQ6qIqJS3F7hkt4T/EyLAVEqUeImjp3TR/QAUuxxQ4N3WXHrmGIHEkNr6uPEUXnk4TEHEzBx4LIhJUbG8ndg70kYCcPIetjwEY3d/ytz2I6k@ss0a7BXReEWmz32SN2mWihmRNMwOCxm9JFVn/PPKXVMuCeqh1l4F7FINYY1IrFFGfsK7o0hgxKPmRQ0dGIJulMk8fWXMJs41obzPUZDtWD1gAKwD7PUMm6E9dF0j6rVP0UCm059gDqEwrrTmze5MUsNAHgX8/LMOPMQBzgbeScUw0fDwFD4A@gc2SFjzZUoTDeQD8MajRM13OsCcFBSM/Hzgi1AkExxv0@@5z1ddPCIOCPUfFcu4YHyIlhJnYPW35k2kZPZmE2iOS40BHPIDkdIiUH6A2jOcJCmQJgaAiHiopeH373D3qDAcSz1e06bi9A188B2bs0LuqUWRjZGCKsY@sWZQvgMpg6Dw4JnOmW2SMSp9sXQRKUCUr13JlYPUYd9dyELjfUgdIaQB26vsGR3Jn4kMcMG@mnnByaHHOh4CO9Aw1LCVDaVGyJPdyBVupCNyeckUYTv19m0niXJT3lZWqzmtpcaxmQOVEW1xOKMqgBwsnr5AS25G2Y8/nWwjjh@brnmL3Y@MIfOrbGpC4TunVnbNip5EIcyUzS7SRFGcl0SqyZ9a7cN@1eKrkBuNiAhJNirVvvNs3qSe1a8PkkIZpzjAa7q5HqigKSGuoUZ8oIOAsZKNnnUmCa83O8NlY5estzzlgx193OuEOc@BbESwcRBOiQ7FmGMU5lZVVEMoFwS8uNHstKei2OoMBV8ySdjCfT80WnGKCkCwXFznpsOki2rPEQmQ2oFNsbA811EXe7OmCPhyOaD/xchnUIr2kYBMpCNPHcSALV7gAhDfGIuiTvchheQkIZxDDrQos92ejNdWQgAtCXfe8GNbYcZA0oTzjyAOmwMVF9AE0DgXlBtnhBeErkslikUxsICsbWMVhZ6pjQCbC7AU0PcH6ubACe0zgMxMY7yRztGekXOKpxvmDWYXBM09kIyIN7wboG0hwgPgYfUDCRCfU/D5he5vRZVtIKhcU@dqOL@a6yJX0FRPqtcmtPwsLPdyYkNKwPPLal24OJPgB64dgQRO92jbEfECooiecDKbo@3pCjFAyesjeMJR5eT5sGkZA3mqWBRJ63XjAU6khdAp5dAoYM@T4uCLCe6QJZgpH8WuoAcHYtceEVgixk4JWwIgshBwBIZkyN7sQHqgYIfD40u0PAWcydzekiH4SuJw9O86kDZZf6UdKYGbXxQIvJSuSE2VgZhYQtejMeGFwxqsaCAzX@vMPtMeveaEnETpRFGAjmXGVFlwH37ohz5NjOkkihIqNoEWTRh7cDcGJHyBHDwBWyXdRZIzY5aiJoM6Aa0PMB/4a@P/aqME6Y/nDSkQFTlGP3Yt8/sBFZFN@9MH2HmzuW0wGy7EH/VMIUlO6kY06vFYjcojZ87cXOgAHre6wOI/ebCWBdKtn3gGCS@w4Cz3kJRLgpCv4UAJCAZKioVN8jUrwHROXowu6mhAWkFDJMwL4riGDAgFHVfIbM22I2X4PT9Vwi2HxmZAWhFM/tkkGa40kxegSnbMW@sVC0e@Yx9g1BgEdftzwD3vbEstA6sTmVS3FeQWSXsW98A0hbipIzR2PL7Jp@m/uyBw8CnoKtgYCHbFMfeSYRwnwjkKRlICgAEww/HFr2nSNidlMiFOQbVwsJG67ruDxdf@g654wcECw2X6k7zgipO/uCGC7koEGmNW2U7YOxlIZSfSkLEY2pxC8nk/Jrx7RTl8m1tbVkNdmAEXNtbRNMG2jaRFMaTJtkksiEcDKaKESGTOjbpBDodpK8aoYxT8UT7A5THO3fmuOU3qxWcycZvakGbw3fItQzjBgALeEL4kmK9ToaRVFonENB5U5/sfQ7OOoddV1zHFTCZ/qZzu1BLeSoGqDhHBcFgxoyL7fXyajuAncBwkB3mHKTrWa2ddK6bPXSratkBkOLNb3egUJBeqmRPHCdCbAhYjNfldQTUWzmgPno1JPZ5HoqVZZAjANJRPykLKZ1XtuppAGjYarVSkKlBvXT7A5dim@a0UQxqirIBzI8wGunkvJlGdLviCdiOglhxWQGRLd6Mgk108VK8KjQ2JcWKujg@Td5xeyk0zHq3iCV4n1jOAU3FHoXgx9O3r5F2sXj6EQYZk10zuWNAwBl3w5hZfS8JrSGXp0@Qzq6kManTp9LRTv42H2yFzOm1FqfHuztPq9TMkPdOwWeQhogrAK8MtSK25OBGliTnhFbBgNkA0zdWU5w4gATH3S7THIYgUldnom54aLLVsQGtIYYT4dJ1mixCN4Q8ruzUAaKhNwp5G38SzfMEgdfmqcoyT2g2DtHTxbmx0anwE@wrmch8y25vABgVda5Y49ekYxRZfsko9nAYAJuAX/Zi@YCbMeWkBaG4pwznxCfEAEIckNuCzkJcwEGI@6bUxCJ4zifErD@yLEi97/j2CCcGvIXRA0FBoQcp6oMeSn/f8gZKbnrzXoncPpgHFt6F@j9YnQtgbUgQqBAirLcR6zdiPi6cEBy/F1lBFaqq9tYfz2T5NSJ6Q2xekGWwFHA7UOtopCKkztUa/usC1zuAGramJo@l1qhhx9hkMe6lxJRTtricgZiGfLImKlw2o4YWKcLEr4BvDL68ukStmufma5jYyXLuxA1kKIatsG1yJdVL6DR1ta@9mh1/S6LHGrshrM6V7fzsV6v3K4Hvct2LGfgsHUAQNSUZY7Y@zZOb4KU4@tj6FHmW6qgrYEDov4iDhpGNGFazEXypo6QCsHLr2EUYMsLPQNYUeaj/a92gQ1RC9ks5D@0ZemKCjkXy/UyomOXzQCCJQAL8QZb8itjPLxwF9DJc4J5E58mD6lj8pksHVhIyFXQw99S0PlOzl2gn4devdC0rOy7JBPg5N28XL1Q@gVuhXcbKGH8mjO6hlWxEOmNBp@1LxKulrJAt6KpAqk/cnxd@VwGEo2PGHLIkskET0muJRVJwqdAXkxrMKVnnClIpWYxT3eN7tK4p4bRVdAXBzcWGpZWT@i5ompacNn0gGLyd1gHUcjr5R@k00jYKXdR2jzTMMgfDydGzOgOHSa0QMSYL5kAA8QQZGUJah4YQJRLomDBclDMdyYg1vUMyxyZ/j5N2Fs2yi4yEW8ZqVbguwP0ZhbBoWkAQ84nHGaDDE6qz8Yoe8DhnwMlp1hBxJd5lbpGT1mfxfbUcVyQKz2m0pyCFlX9KPBQHG/ck/0pRMBD7dL47oXj/LODR7vtw63jx3Vl4rmKZXaARvSM9giEWQu6w4oL84YzhLuAO6btjEwoURjl21PrueP4nHnAVYP7XXEMGMbx5FH7yf72863n3w4yRyO6OZpYOuaxmrgGEMVxRDC3RtN1Og7wFvZkZUzAXBxsHzwJY/nsxZP9rfaj3cOD47loXk8sU1enyvh0sKpAnyEIU@Usr/oDq7e4nENi6sIsQkBsUOaqMZBNmSTBU0I3nihKZTJ6IIuMw6Mk4SywjvPcLtPUbKXS6@jlslHsdfP5Ul/v93p5TS0X@uWCVsjCo1SsGOwdgUuSMaWZGzDxWRGcQMI0IPP0UuV8yOGAKNoFjuViab4i31sy1y0UjFK@ole6lUpF10q9nK6VS4ZRLPXz2axRVLP9Tlkt527N3Fw2kLWa2UY0AwS9DicLyBOIXwpeC92BZx54vXPW0zSt2C30KzmtV8jme51KtlDuddSS3qkY2X4@p2pqr6up1TAszqgClRhCgyFXaQNrGnpJKniKsXAwnW9iWmIM16ADgpPIIYkZh2vIKDgEHnn0mAQryDg1G7gX0D1cP8YpmsC9iO4jXD2ecbJkjRwDwDIB4iKy7HZCxwo6RsvHCwurQCoD@rnMf3WgIOZLNXuFkZ/jAvRc@S5VldzP/H5/wVkj51MJhzJr5pwjZ778vLjwGxT2htdS4Ci@PMXHl62XxnfDaylwFF@Bx4fL3cuju@azDDSKrEiR4fL40riueSwBjGIqUUzzS@ozvzL5rVpPD9Ja6r0yUBR3heLmS@Xt13y1oh2slCM28w5yDJzYEwf45ycmztv3F3pMLJLAWzEhnEZYnEia@WizZRImnS1f3xHmI@LEwLRPHRKcI1M7K6sFjCWKYnRq3QzZB1GDHgugNzJ104ePX6NOnx5LAHDQvT4zRx407RkM/TDU6spzeuEE6LIcLE7lLiTfMfoTkIKUjmmj@Q4wqVImyH6nY64ChZrAnQfhewlYlT2fgCSqyXlZDcVeXDoBms3nYY/3Dwiwo5MQtzj/zxYq35@4PoQK3v/5Oz1ohJtNNNQvSBaMDG3bOCf86K9ssSAoWuixvHVnoz5VDJnuirKr45KrbkWG5VFT60vSUHdHKHIFzQ0Iig/AhFtwjeecz8WE7@WJVBlV8uI6A7PNEesugSbYa0siPDESsi1H71E1cFHYNCiQi43Nm8GYcqFwjuGBkWdVQktWLthsq4A/nPgT/sTdAXc1oznG@7YuGkBmC3pHNYBF1jumcUuju/rppOdIwOlRkTFjxSWws9LTZJ3Ut/RTbmyjcXnxeQFdczAAfiJ4rwI7H4JsQ0Kpck6vu/DCsyfeWOpAY/nQcchGXWF0SwquxZ@rQMxg81xkWF1rpkWPezR6hFyELsDSUUXjfiZprtLMa9Vs6Z0LFNWHH49lmCAxOEBz6t10OpvDYS9a@53firQ6PI6VFL5SWR6a76TiVbJMvFL4DiqJTyBTmYM9VXc0LAxc5ki3JK03Z1xJ0cOp45lpCSjN20hdS/cAtfygOYwzaD563IbuODJ1QexyZ6ZbkH2WnXALwKrV5IBsBb2661imh13bWkVBry/AzdLEvWz0mJuSNpdVbI94Jm8oRabldMHp@riUuwLR7kHl@CoqrlPPYY7srKq0rnOO90rWYuicGfy5fKB7uzRX96BYkkUoYXaXjii97l2YituB6LG8Hk@X5svvWkvdF/tAOMUxL6DdE68903I8dkTP26pl4EIw/lyO0fM1aOq2ROtB8@blwYJMjZkczLKuaFfdGjhWsTxQdHisbPyJ28cxIXjfl/pF1EtV76ZeIX/k2GrwXkn2TxX39K62o6UJFxft54y3jMDLSFiwKLm6gCBJ4E6c5YXby5YppKxweXlVA7jd4bl@Eb5/g5FlVe2GI8v4gvhtYP8wQKUMBt/lPPhvklr@9tR69yNPN6It3VWIucY9tQwYyOh5o0mZllU/MoSazd6fWPWtiTExltKqg85rAze33yKF3D9T2aAYiWC2E2eEcK4zgnobyI/3yjWO4Wi7lcDolgmd/E5OZym9GwOPPkaR@xAMh2i4GXBgT8YLjbsgxdnPb6@54Tjs2U5vIZPo87EUqXw3P7XAyHsG3bcKV1wYxLWtei6bzQb8zdz89YLlNqErF4V9bfLnQsLkMkt5BouzIe6ccXkas6lUaHrz1JNwUvN@1ElbNSNAwJWKYpu24V/gc1WTLKO2HcexPqYJgej2TOTfgCvFhZ@7mvIGbxTsBmOzuQ8PZ046/VWzHnxACqRTqD0UvG/Dhvmp13s1s4RL1tBLB9est88DzU3k3pUKDPM0ucS3TlirGc9gRkWVy3Lp1h7J2VmnY1g6f02L@dviq8i5W@OLWJaAT6a1LVwP4ytgsxXV@DW6Nb6AyjJ7IOQMjZFB1lukA733euKFr5VAUwfvJd4yrTeuCjc2gVDY@FxYbZtjpXzHBrHM192BgXKNhavigesq4hzOqi@t3P2RPjD4oarbqOdsqgO3DnNpcGZcPulR5bvOuhCMb/24HRWgM50aF174Xhrh04sutOdkdPdU3bV@36WNSnd1dFlZuphwB69oD52hPTSGfCdQZFvVPQAjfX4c7rZCQP4Hwy4j@jS/S2m@Zi3Hsu5Ts0gfObV0nP7SPO3iIa0eBP2oeC/0DngErzunAGGspwqiQX9VvxkaExiyPMd3xoZEtlWgFk4W8ecqKhou7vyms1C3zhBAjYTv3zT@O2XTge744zG92mNr4tGDgkp0tm5ZU@5RMvfBCtPn24443hoDp9MdmndlqWPovm2eKuGMELfeKtmO52rBZNIjdJYtEyrPvZARG@rz/kf42l/VpMHkEh@2IsPyNq6ynYnrXmBN@I7DPMs5n9GHxf0T0TQuX31Aw6ocBCuDS7yJG8CddeEOsluWQIKFxJUIRkw4MtySkQWGRV05o7SwvXOud@Ry/LGKL7pWfsrU3Prtx0yJBtseaHLQnJu5BfcF/FlYjF46WNnDycC7Se74hH0PWCx8LG3prQEeaL7W0LxRYQTS7eC1qr41S8Ht2/BuQ8tNjFtXVwq3Lq8QnGpJumPCqw0vaMPJymkzyxx7/MmkvraUYbi5hHwT6mK52By0T8/o87UQNN3F6Y0cFw8RAUshdV3D6@JUOlJkzj9x6mM7A6DMksVmwCHs0iLcXLVe2vzRiCd9@cwY6Li98omJOy2tJVgBsV5fvL4r0m9NdM/81sTxjaXxXV/Aviu6p/rA7D5eqPkwsrBGgz14/LWA9uh0s/LPh6ZH5zdCwy1zTohkHG0Rz9rA7y@T1q5N10enom@fVpljlIK930zaZ@Ee8ciACwbory9Na9lMvDMmufGCTLdNwps@zcwG76VYtXwTwG3Jn09G44kXvJanTvt05qeoR6fk7p2bQBalN0CN2VC3/OXT2HMzs8BzBYPkzLiKC//KtJwB@6qcZcCiwaCNTPkShNuG4fpQ96FH2EsQmNK@50IpTnpILi/YG8AJI8ck0zb92yd4fF8HGSl8Y2H4YIOnEJUn@JQffmwM0vHyGnlyKwcDY/tF18JD8R8rCXCyC1h4RIfW0Ridm5/H@yAZYyeIMBxdbON8Xl67ddGnikOqY098CXf53zamFG8dU6psWi7OoQZLfWv36QtxHkNo@@tdfKgBguDEsy5mppUbD64hnmkDs7aaFi9Ch9LEI4NUGjynjZp3hNka4@kpIvmPnGUSz@EFjD73FplgAJmMHhldXHm8M@1nzlNg3WAoGwPRHT03cMvANVqyPCAGe@J0dQvqp3dnMkcU7ZKxYiZc62OjA@1rzUzLebFlET/SfX0F70QThyQBRqY7ccW0Oob7mmYE58yrhNrFDD02piSGrEYY3gslv9vlDDdOyy30ketrO97YcWz@JCKchZf69HZiA8MDPe6/4i7j/uWF0W@pkLZY2oMzvt3E6PGDe6uK6xodx@JPLMIKcmCbfHOB7pqGpzwx7cmU3JgEvNtyMYdv483KJZzm8IbQ2c5NkLGj3b24WY1vFfauSVLAEp/pHi35L5dpFnYS339X0VB3uw6unQWGj1w5mzsSdgcdj7ZK860JHWiUKRA0vTsJ9QrckVVr1BnRY6VMMtfSz40OHrnr0PlRX58uYyIXj44FjtcOb4UkDTt@kaUOQeoR7x7IrotsizVujulBBP18KZqEyT0zje5bXbyDlka9iOaSFZ0k2qUdaXETHLA5liH5Q9xjqfj@KoLxzDyd9O6x1hUuoExGBq5ZL67crEQqxxsSRjjLV@kjgusawdZt3CUIXT80I9WVtlaiLEYP/4PtzxQYmNvFPJ7gn0ylAZCzu/cFQOYnrh287oN2h47n983pwRh1ODnuKvqCxSpAEHjx7oCm9ZuxB2c3SM1MpJDAywSnisDNdIOTy54c6kyK0wks6lDhWQAWR6UJE5T9IVMyI7hUSk@nRTHGA@G@jIENYCEUKX1BhRBcn4zHgHnyCdbss2aTJS6n1WxVvWJ1JlQFdnLCY8WL1BPsTsekseU5D95M6Cf1RFKSkolky66ybDICNywQGpaC6wuwfZNePL@zKuDanBxSxRSVuMYVXkBnRmUyQ93uWQZ7YdNiGXB6LlfbwHWCHOMm0F/@cS/QsUO6pEYmCPJQIagjyxkZQ@d8k6cbpA48kI46ejAOkP8srjFC2tliIHz43SFXreOcsxd7x@VAYUegkAssh3wKJ8oFb1xcR8LDhz5vPJ6b6CBZkHAUKiwUcLWTkQ3DSM8fejI7Mulc4cSdnRQI1JTZvouTxb0M22c9A/fb0XFRWhuxHOeUjpBgTn75x1xNCR0aDQ7zhcmTeqK5FPFsqEq6QbpdZwK5DiN5a7hOAJLCSgaJb4IrkaQdi9xFPEpJ@lMAI6VQewglw1WI7GwdMWmXJVHvFp72r5n9VGLr@aefN7Mn9fdspBj/@TuKeBlUnPCJVCl6QoaFILUrRKx57wJ4z3yTTEhMBZ5gdKLWDPjWc94eqDOMIxkeqg1xzHHGQa8hDVCk8CjCxkCRQArN1M6hGpERKY8ihDXOSY0IHd2ykYiR8jIPOhhYRYqa97p6IjXhi2PSkc8KkCCqYtHBxNVN0RlTVImBQRJT9o4NEcmAE1ILWbDxirRQC8uovh3uxs7N75JXHhmdCe0UPdNkrVCn4iTa9Y0GmYDSOqgNqfmyNdWyUmta2j0B3i6o1FZr@klW@xJq3XEh1AMFe97us0eXCbmRfffO0y@YIFwla3xXP5CJxOXh/uHu0fHW8YsjaIWrkPzs8bM9Ia1BLKLjekPHIj1TUC/IZH0E/YlsqPUhxRI620A1hqIYmz9YRaBBXQuSkODGOdK0EPqO4MvCe8ac/02AgKb1TRZi1D4MsNiGgGxYa1j4yRi1ZbEgbKDxh7DMRBqPHSiqGDw7sYSWUlUJrA6VJUFl3bOq2OrCbnK3@9TYnbHcXm2bS0GwxqL0mpE/L@LSKrj6Byn3GAbK//Zy81huLzfB3FJuAI1cwzB7W/tPXjzfXQwGOEZvorr1SiE4UciJM/Y0zqiFKo7oIH8QEBcX6wITKAC3BoMZV7Ro@OcGFCsgjt0RD0wYSvkXYjPEhJqpo6LPkxqvi1SKcoA8SA2Lde3AI3BRc1kMx@i56C55ESMisCdEUYcZl4Ug5jgprJTxCouBsQbVFXa9QyLiAb1OevPsTybscVg0HKMnHu9zK4aqaNTxGPznRqXQpJ2wKQuGM/WESUyD2zLsARQ4hBVrfIxiCV4RQoLnXYjyi7oGIU@91zrN59NG/uCgIIzSlj5GxWYB9DPHN6rszcQhZQQhMYn4C1JzqXO9oNS0XOElKTkAAQr4/nDcovj2947qyJ1x1ozo@zzOTWwcqACIa@kMjgv7Lqqy5ec4ubo8XuVOoJktHCpJJvYCTUwRl@CxM9MzQaKjRugjj2MBpcTSBAVHNa@khoJtWR7wJD0YvoFD8XGoBeZEptNl/IiZZDMhDjgpRyxjhgkxhPXqNzV1wVB6jjz@Kx44QXAUszcXZ3JjTZKg5gYgxAcn1aqo5JXEwSrz3QluHmskbwQJs1AlkzT0R9Yc4BKdhS1D@fC7f8D1FLZ8MP8gME@z22D77cDWB/PvhD6qCrZ/Ftk0sP2Q214q2GQ3lbPN8hmds195Hg@Q86Fwo2BIGELttlSgqMmxuT/fP2ReF/WmYoOOQEiftRWSGUQ8ENYACUeAGWfU0AjOU5i14yyeVPNzwBNALkAS5HGQraH0DPckhXq6qoqCGcdpfpl28RlTvrJOarveTFBdJXBiSrFQzKsKZFI6CyMkTSIDPFTEIxTFKhDG2Jk5rr/qdNnGxgYTvK5uGfVijSOIktBf5oRXUUYTABvj0kKTQRgIMgsBfo0gWCqhp1URg@JollSTSNh6Dsc3YAlTZAAQEZ3tUPcA8JxOUFWAzLYx9YltugilIKDatjOnpzaMSIKIeNyoVPF6n5wdFMK5qbleKs83g/AFgh0hWFVYhrHNl6zlt@yTQLkmA@z76RL8tcH8T5Zo3OSYhbpVbqp6TF1X1IilYQ@PbAen@PYgtyylKVpOUYviHIYKQVSQX@zv7yBK6OFAMbqG@doZe1s7u/ufHRwe3VD5Q5DJ62BJlmxspFuSnGmeRIZklO/FSt3eU46ebu@FVTmfq9kkG0LMdk1ez@ay1K7ndEXqX/AzWTfTJo8bCanZ@0ZMW5KkPdp9fDP2ma8yB7jDj4TcSDUlXl41TzYaLTt@I/l3y9S4xuV1RC4wtTxS4pq8nk3MYqSv/Rj1tXtyeOBYxdPGeAzNd05nZ5cDhzkPDh7GAhQgJish1CriCRk44JM0MyUbGlcY7xHp4xM5pFwzytEc5HGoWh671kwnXKAMbah7Q8vsxGAA76GCQK7KJNTVESlBkb2xZfopMUZTIHVkg4CIpQIF89PqVKa1wRSpcqW4Muw2/WphfGIMOgHElzyceEN26IzZbP7pkRGangM3wh5N@MKRwT6bjACuT6/nBpJYA/gTCQJDRSWjrHKpGnpWoF5tmkYVdpBeE5WsBQWXR71CairKQ2PaMwdAwFNiBnr6JyqwVdEBcCw0qVyzk0DjeA1/ikdx5qv0o7TsTWeR601dNu2eMU2h2pjqCfCn6J48/@IsKQo3cIBU/e2EysGu6fwLO6LuBz1ipi/vWmerRFrlryllrFRQ9Q6eZYdmgRSPfPcJGGF8SvVH@pilJqSM0mMyI2uqlbIznu@KTGpwfRY2S6dJqoYXeQDXjKB9MhHisBTqbk4pdWgddPXsHr7emmPWVGX5BMyUiMgSOKO2A0M5zkWJMZCSIEiVoq1j27Iq5ohjr8wxD8Kgf4y0YzHUyLjEm3Qo0tSrg3VBpWaNB3NahWY9kNdqpVINWmOR1FQYoMVNKi8rEO0SEhJyqVC/wdFkqDXUMY7K6HFmGsjCw28atm1ABQHOjHQYg/UJIJkrZsIvSmRmOqkphTjP4uPgrDNkdFFX9W7y0sLly4RSo8mZ2hWMqa9aOKj2g2H1QvkfFVmpXaYSVv1CAUZHbKQSw7qazq2n0wl7PZWwcah/8ADndK4SwEm0ZRCRpgAkJSyxBvgMnEc9YdcS@kYq0atr6xQCrCCkXUKA954iXyb0KyXxAEbqDLi4vPOmEh6pO8zKsnoF@cMeklAygDOXqB2OPieBySfMdBrzICfamIH3SusoTTS7daTQ9FEt4EaVwSjobteoatQSNz6mwSswcA4aGgi7hoQ92GLeDoFnmqpzy/xW8B484W/iKR5GGwcNb579FxZ97k9YAnqXJE1UXLkk1zcJFThNQSWiNaOLIhCTX/86rhaZkEpsFnNn6WQhW4OHWiuxAvsk0dLycRZ/COK6si64wmXrUfmMGX2t@EaSmnpffnNyeHp4@KXYSiXjOwcvBTUPoCVWofu@V4lpKy72cVc8vq7E4sq6@qCkKK9evQJ2F65mQ27MQ8knYlNKnjRTJbA0SqX1TLG8nnmYbFNWxJSmiUfMNBXWMsderwe3M6SPuqTi/GKbm5gWGODPArfRtM/dZpnhIIFrGDb0uguuqhfirFXS9fV0Xnto12Qtq/3yF2tXmcvD9sYvvztSjDV8HeDrB1dP0XykFj5ZW/tkezufz0DlcfPhV4ff3trayj/KFA6bhc28lF3b@Ku/WFvTtA1NWTvxPPUk2Tz9UtCyeUH@5c@Th4ffanseth9eOaaCEZ9luFVWKLBT9hau0z7DP5nf9ubMOpo7/bc4QAKzXCdik0wWcsmjl0ks7tu4qqrxC/q1qRrWmNrYLP2XHx28ifvxhqZ84cLbj7@JF8txbgQD2HKh7SzeiG8gWPEqfqHU63Uwlv7Lv4Pwjc8gHvS52IBHoxDGVbyIN6Q6BXkXbxTBoGoapPv/fOc7sXhjiojQ2N9jWkNb57iilh@oD9iUX6wVV8v5g4fgHF6hV3QxRVW1Vtiec82NTRs5D6Hw0K7MmXOL2j3EjDgLsIEMHwOH3/8prj189YhtNGCoxatafRihmsJKZcFxoDvXwPYkcn8uS3DJ7dBeQ6sUFCFermfaPPkIV@NzhmsFjp4sKHtk/0i4Xbz@@v/66x//9Y/o92O6/1MsHi7uS82zxkkjvJjQQPrEAttTmz3ll23DH@7Qii7oACabzcoSjzca@KB/YCMTva@5BT6NyEIQsyC3wAU0g9KNxd9DmyD2sbPGwsUaCovMVASeazI8nSvZrGyIAptwrcGP/nBFVnyukUvgTCA3rzXWuO26lfrG4s148@SkSp3p/hdbHnf8LBaXgDSk08@BZwyQ@T7XC7hluR3YIqSOx@L/oFcjxuKXcJ2kpaurpvwyXasFf2ClapENL26CPJ1cSdLGy0Y63aS8NRtBJjekk4bM2jy/9Hi5AfGmN5obdWeHbrmNdSQl806y6Dw8edlobizGEUTz8GEaO/NDiKeROGHAxEPNXm1cNa6aG1dXGxvw36DnVfAG16uNG396za7aCqDoujrBRm81lUZLaQUNegJ2WWmgi6y0wNCAdxsAm81Y/BLxhTVPSENWXWqqxcKJxKhPrFfRr@sxVlXXtZxSmH5S3NVicU0QlHX0eocjE/AXlVgcufQKZ9Yr5PDqw9f/B96tD1//G7BC1vAzZOT72MZf5w3@nrzF3xsff8dd/D1/g7/jt/h77uPv0MPf0w7@YvE6Y8AiJTazVvYsq56qp2AwWRY41GF2qPZwSMgaLHuRvWDZkaP2wGTALwsmM9tn2QHL2llbVcETDD7L@mjqw2sAvz7E4sLPzGYx8uwZg1QsHGhIvSy937WZ2Io1mfDKAN5GVpNyNikXk0nzpFAcvxEyyXarmTypxRWv1VI418e0fI30Cl9dsXZ799mjdlvBftB66hzM/gcHo3nrrf/RgfP0wBk58D84OHgKrZ5@mJYewlVvpDeC12a8UdtsVSVEZjlA67iysdlq5CQ0F9OAohq6pT/ymsUI78ZaKwYi8RdfnNe@@AL/52e18xoZIisY2rUIIADjBnDkDhDBF7UaGdAM1xnFSjY0nn/RikzcoHxxDk5fMGDSo7@yYPsH@Jv///o/fcFSzRMR@sHl1UaKLhF/onh5dXkVPBtiKhVYUhvwQwewY5DLqwYaCegSTM2UeCJeXXE3eKbEDR5hA9PYaFDgGSBQjHiUJqXLH6l/2Demza9WErgkkF5TwdJbqzXNZsVaB1yi@Xf9Ha3iiDXa35Lo4MobSGyqSBCFfK2mrnOzltdqtXxgKZVrtXJgTqRSlZtXI7upFotVLZ8XxVotG8CCcFYLjRCF4endGnbvWnwsYm55p09lcQqQPiaQFKrCgwep4PMTm@MxCOtqJfvuXeTUbvdMt91G99y7d0JbwL0w9UoB7Nnyu3dAeJIiiPHPHL4Km5JU9onWoBQqIJ9r@RJ4M1XRZmkOdU/3fTf11hxnBNwF7AkiKQDOZh23lfzVD7/73VayjrsjyDWvYgSYCitsbBTzjUYxD@ZiGUouJPh2m9QgXVHFq4Qi8PKCGJ6MB15quSSS61US/Vl8g202oKN6eLHLqzg1IMsXxFTnwhAvwSV0UysV7sjyxVQ5XQl@9TWRNdZZ8Gs2m7l0fr20/vDk5OQa14/EtHap19Wr@qVexTmiq1o30DCPpzr0Bw9yFajFcrbWirXbj7aOt9r4cTpcAYfxj6EjkeUYrm6O3WSTJvQKlZMmluiklUxWaw@pwdVygcWTtQBOSgKFZ@UKFTzueTGzj8e7phTrtXs9PmZqKQcDa2xMO5FKWdbDxVyXOf3@GjhCi7EOrrt7hmWFKvnPHdfqnZs9Yy0WP3yytbN7nNE2YIzW9rZ2MtrRi@24itbCzE7eObQ/3916dPACAhw@2d062v10//PdF4fg7sVev9UNQzcmhnHenkzO36DWdqNtjMF1drWNrunpr1/rY7pYjRPk8/MPP/3@h5/@Tx9@9sMPP/v@h5/9@Fdf//j7cP8x3D/k7x/@20oBn7/6@p/90Yc//Bk4/ie4/yPcv/jV17//HX6T/c/h/ss5tz8P7jk4frNqvLGOFyBCWSun12HEW69UABnIdSMGaf32r77@0c9/9fXv/ATufxHcP7l5/@4vlt8//t7qG8P96I9uh/nhv4P7T3hcIewP/5C74fsG/B9yuN/5yYff@/f8/1fBD40/@/B7f46PwPJPf/JXf/nhu/9B08p/9a8/fP@HH773ow/f@@6H7/3gw/f@sfbh9/@1mp1//NGHH//pf/2zP/mvf/a/0P@P6fkn9/l/@Mk//Zv/82/@77/5s@D@Bdz/Hky/@Jv/AGj8d3/6U/z/6E//7j/@FP//@7/8uz/9X//ut/8VGf6AG/7ff/Fv@fNvv/v9v/3eP//b73694vn9W59f38P96/8OLvfP533iuU@5Ptbl698oP/8ttTFLBXCA1OczDZja7QuD1Vgsy7LBAzrhj//Jh9//LcDt3wNIsP3PYIM/t4DXD8jy5ZcLfmma6ZDSX34JIuKXgaj45TzQDxh7pwADnn34DgC@JF9@sQgKEv3fEArAWAAVgi0kTiC4i5I7/@rrf/5zdI9CoutvzceXDV3nYBMI/C4s4g@wM0fFmIf9AZKDDz/9zoef/@MPP/2DDz/9bRwLpHwls5WBMfz2eVQALNwDDgGL94EDQBXFRJDn12IaGNY2cN4vpqZfvYJGWAMTyFfrsUIObDG1QWYVzRAQpP91imSaxqkSuKexfAVsYACnKRnAKw1e22n8TnI6Nq2DH4HiB5YZGhtlnLPDiYQ6xIuBeJhMuwwyC5tuUywQsp5@ztrr9SkPmEaHBsXAMEPo9FxQNSFdrj@CBOvTRwzjwsjTsVfwflVvlOvTBkb3nrIAcaS3IUmAwu83p6eN92CvU5wAH5s@eg9ZKdfT6UYZXOpUVEot06Y01QIVjsqeZlRudGcMdzJuPmTsE0EtC3ymA6qSBdD4TM@gN2kicBP8W@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@azSAr5f292JxwPkhC9d4JbMnD2X6BGBv4hrkO2Ds0f7n@0f7B8/kR/tHwGt/m2m5rByLX11d9aOVCbIa7ODgIIbEBiSnnIrhr7psMpmQbwfsV1M9Np6/auNxTNMkLSflVEnN4f8Og4b/@8Nr8NfwCaFyWozFEI0fAIl@oHJjoTgzZtG4EZwBb8RoBbQJKHQSww9GNU9iG0rkeYzH8Z9BWwDy2uwJbgT2HXbs8A2n20Z3BcTOkH/6fMd1QDL6zWG2dfuUez0y@bngyOuxjopBvZHpD1dAvBiP8Gib4f53i2F31IEM4loIB9iGh2s5zjKAEntxuKKUTyM1HrjZgPR4APjz/U8fH8@9j3e3dh7Himz74Nmja69CAFRgT3b3jiNrifuGQQtRFN/effLkujV4AUWskSi8xgqlTAYGFnjgO0MXveXEyxBElVdzHLqvg6DdZPmTGozv5dqmilMfhYRSV@3J4ROU0i3n0AXi2UKZ@7208Xm9oSf6QH7r21Kj/D6dL5Vz1mVjd4hfRHVrrjH1B8aEvQBCjFseKyo/v2N6sccgVI/wm0v4fTU/hueIe/hdZZw06eAHjidjttIRXuiERtccDGEEOHdCgFhH1xncH3tB@Hl5GmrrVgefp0FuN3ysJeC4zm72WTYm0yyzVikXypWcVs6UK@V8QS0WChlVy6ilcqkC1DirltViuVBRM@V8JZeH4QJ8C5VSLA5k1OwrCgyFqiDAuwrR2l38TMAGfm/BkYeNWJxPVbG3KV2EZo3sEyYYEEbAD1Z5Pu3qXjfrgpbHIxc5lUGMOuuy@N7eTnZvTxC20YKz6TtZQeihpVDOZkvbgmCQzw4MaZogODwMeAGYzy3Z7PaOIEx4BKh0RBCGaNktIo8uCCZadrb29jCd12jRMDyAnXIfbrFCSwnAbLTkcsTkC8KbKDqA2@IJ5Smnu2jBNNFnj/vsgJ8gfBrmJ5uFGJ5zOB7D47CsW1uCsM8tW1vo8xkVvMCz@k20bNElCC5YAAkFYQCGgWsYtiB0wIioKAhdMHUvdHDDTzKgIgrb1wXhglcQVpEgTAla754KwIwG7pjM48eP9aHfMwb8unD5uwtZAx9zOtnd63z6aWcw6LgXW7ufPkefzz57rL@@mLidQScI1mnD5UAY8DkdXVy/II/77bZuLfX5JvjY13zaF20D89bW30CegmuAiYzan4HPZ@AzXXLx2OAaAWgHr@0RvLf1DvmEF/nQe9rpCDVEVP9ibOAsHfYZ@vB6ZqR3XaeG9ml9LZlKZi6axexJjZzZKCVeZmtX6NtP0Uf/kCCKlxfNaT17AgJKSQuOhaSE1lQrmEJmbbQJNK66pm@qWj49raJGWaefZElJ3UypD9bfpp6Jm1ouXxVam5uS0FRPNjW1XC2WXq5PBEGs4nMzV6q@TWWTWcbwITZLJ5ulwlyIUimtK1q1VBJrV1ATPoxKnYlvtNup1Lmhn4oi5hVZJ8g//778BRXRrPVT08y0zjPFLsTatK7W@FFolr0RVw91cUzwy1o8xgFEN93MVpFapwS1UhYgfUVJiSJSI6Qf8H71RbhyE73mDAtGfsmsKvHP8qnloijjAYO202/Tp4nYq3lIZJljX@BpIDoJHG7aI@HCq8aOkcPGAUBnqO@ng18CpWPtIOBx/TGMz1@opUos1giYzEP@UZRaYP308Y4MfGdgQ60e8h5@ANpxZfxwqb/gwzVOhE7HMDzJjw3citcN3Xb4GV15d4ofuDcdu3YpfSFdzYc4Al6ap4HHFGp0Gh8P/KJ6E7PH9HoDTHqPpSh9povnVM52o1Fv10fGaOxfgGTDV4GhVGHwZ5MR22YcFk8PhWcn2vVtqIBszUYVXwZaE9P4NNbooQKT7fr25aRaBdirmlGnz1sLcTxxtWnXJ7an941Dw8XDPvsHME4beKqmO3zV2kXAHajsyyup4TJ7Voh9j9dRdHSDMnSJGQo82vXsVW0@1yldanTE2qDeRNB3@NiQBOFEkprvTkBgqsUa0PtqF3G97k06/Btw2Q7ISsXaFNzUUr42ZJ165@W05tbHwOKzmgW1OCe5ML1G8O8sGEjbcrs@ndVGrt7UQHbJZkJpRsOdXBktW8loKoykMMJCSLhLYM/DrcIN/irKOikrJTAmZLLTrKxmVEPNgKj4yuy9EjO@s2tDi2SrVWwYaFSywltnYlpbt1I9h@kbErUxdPEaZVzPDNnYhEcKwj03dIsCiKLEUtKbzWK6kBXF2hvItZtI9eRtcTNf66W2WVsEB@AN4NZYMV/r11MvxcU6FmupNbHuGW@oPpFUUGWM16A5AnnOm4yaWbZWVDOXUlu6snTPT6glrdqcJJqSCqXNvhtsCF81hBNomisGUgebX3gB1qMGbiFZ4MzKjN2YuY2R37QMaEW1otUCkNg4IFIpIYXfB@YbR1PJZElLJsVkDWcO1sA9IHJEkZJAHpMP1E0B2B2hKlQ0kBPniNuNLPC1uiKIcFexnumNWb4Si1/Gri6vNub3wnyTXVzoaSm0PmBskE7EmEIr4XI7ztbIJMkNmt7Zqm8Nnm/VAuitnVi8Shu/Zrt0WCs4aSspax@7/J7eaLzk7xbuO4FUY6TSpslOgv0GWg7K3JuzQ/m8yxivVb4dQ9lIN5RWTBCob/M1vHJB5Dll7@OkHZ7tXPYDolR9ilI4S@lV3mebJ@L7Z6Z1Wc5JDRIfUyz@Pg01gnvYGsr7OAwLV1TRwU6xy8vx5SVIx1d4elzLFWJx2wk3kYFQ6gMZhPGkUBBwMsVg46PKy9LL8sunLw5eHOyxh9lquVqeFy1aDzMZNakmN9hDYGPN57sgtrxjTkF9b39G2@fitXh1nMzlk7mFYPX4tJ4PV2lTaqMhqRsa2wRcZVWgUH21KGXfNTjiNcijqIHPh9/6SX66UQa7BqxiFeq0kNYaDXVdE@PjD1//GzyQdbn7@dYTlsQC/v1f/Fwr/f1f/EtaGUxe1XihS3GARKNaLMVP4jwL@RITwcLXp9V4Qwnc1ZIqxj2J2yB7hbj3LtCPkdKyZfDbOeA2oQi1Fq/EY/Hy01fvGNsA@bHRGwxMjUyKsiCTJaogZcGfvccJqPfS2iugJ56XUHDjYgWBw1mT9UajsU77GZONNB4k1Ao0Wd@8qp3wWQ2UQ9Zt@hneOv6Ml5HDuueBPbSBdX3DYIWGykBwUZQPv/X7mlb8@7/43Zb4rv2u/S2gsJVKpahq8V/fvOKBrh0N8mLYfFNrFY/kSmW@Ox8J92uPf7g7PJlIH20GDhl1tqCKBtPBswunEAB5AjDj50CBiaiyex6DjAVD9ls8lxOYO7pnFPOhzbvwcEc5zvfhsUSvqigD0x9OOnQO8di92PcP6JSGAvhigrBP5o7ldJSRjpMM9A0oD4QogECV4RNbgXESD1nQNzKRb0WFE21SZwRF67UBrI3FSonVGIOUx3houjXt9wU6bW1YvSNjrJPaGvAPj6Tu9xAMlRrRWe7wGPECTxWdIaYaN1hyh2@ll@gwuEOsjJcMjw9S1TJSVGHg4Q4BjzMHh5Jol7wgow0/eyyEO@QBou@gXtMQnn/WPgoQfSh5FgLLiLpUAs6hPl8ilqbyp8NM4Iwwd6B8zKxBojMHSohy4zIzo7sDUthlo8ojSCsFzSqj/samWj3JcF6zrlJ906l1k23UGTDwqJuFSoIVSlos@6YL7JpantPaQswahZwvR7oe5AQAeYPgKW3UVoVnDpzOa9LQFCiQQPyTQ7/g4D6qxEIjzsnYgeZWdt4xfQKAoY0AMKQywNM8vIoyC6jamQzwmAT2BdlxB4rpeROjUCrnKUM6nr0OQYG9XQDVlECdtEKZw6POUSkq/pBZxplhkTKBINuo20/nnZLwDLfCoKpCZNKLIqEOVOVCSaEWUpUMd3u0u/dk63j3UYZJagHB8axa14lgU3OVy73T5N@3Jt4wQCMMwruv3CnmOZKnvEzyoZIUg6w/nK/29HyGwwjwq084IzhOJesUzDVG@IktHjEb6z2kVRkKYyeD8/h4EJ6f9zI9zMrEtRBvwsoNe348LiBKY1pxRMGFz7xDGCxYwNuADQjPDaCVtAJqIKBubR8wErWNEOYKyw6uA2GVpAZXpyDsWPjNvSQqr5qntknqOzpLHqO@bxjSibStJYkuoMKGYT35iZesdYFtD3kKdpaaiJdBCUy7j7lI8Yo7drYvwvZLTYKTNAJUiAiMsRgdrfnlXyaBz4ji86yUL16e6S57WwcMpR4nc6K@a9GJxVSSq4GFYG9l5DmCE2x1vxYF6Di9Cxm13Nm9naFp9VJv59MYA6tp9lPpdLdez4mXkKQ7BuLkjYEYGijMiTV06y@4RZ@pV1otG/Inr9vGOfvy6ZPH0OTPDTqg3nx5sp5QMsDaijUsgl5PIdCjg6eHuusZriiP8b0XiU0p/EpGkIgMrT3ymtkTyn1GwKIp2AuBcg4MPyi9t31xrA@e6SMjldST/GgYJmVCo5gbuszlo5qZTotQRL1pnizUUV1YbFxBvBzUCWroGv1aByr6tHbl1c9SA7Hmw2s4n0QBkqhrGsXuQ6C6B49rtW7iN7MfHz99Uk9u6AxjrS/pFcl0J0IOQBRCGDrzvuW6@sUC6gBVIazy@elOQhi40kmhsViWDUVvJIFlXZmfJw7ppJBlOTlD4F5qkgkwzq3fbNKaO8OCi7FRRwc@tH26eyxkIKw7MUR0tHF4uyCixRUX1MM0OLohpaAh8OIIYer1/IMH5MaVltTrWjYrAmrWriA2DzA3FYk9bu3K1eu9VFSR@thcoiRBkzVFt71zVH0NLG@2UNp0XBgi6j3gIR94QELqqN75zPQvHniAbfVQ4cIDfnK0vpZfLx@Y29/6snJUfJTqdj5ThYzw2nNsENHc8XwGXP1c5mwR0Fi3y7GLMoFqMLu6MtZPHSXfy3bL2bJa6hmlglHO5srdgpGrdIBL7Pbz5U6vUtJLhW5HgcHNpyDyyMSvMgkc/THZ/v2SXcWYlUHk7/dV4NZ7hUq/omVzuXynXOhl8/l@WdVzuWJPK3cqndu5tll@UNwK6S6OHdcp8CermbvYDdoehBb/Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 HnHnHnbqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1nuPLconsloPrs  \puts~-<V=>a$f 16=B->8~+4783l{>Ehar Cr;rextgeu U 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

cperl is separated from standard Perl 5 with `-1%2` (see [here](http://perl11.org/cperl/#Incompatible-changes)):  `-1 %2>0and 9or 247`.
Space before `%` is for Cardinal.

Answer (score 3):

## 248. [Granule](https://github.com/granule-project/granule), 11555 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWmp771zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@yFbemjTk9nAGG4Y9fwKfoCgyi6pxRm0afI2FPH9QxMvmt4noOOJcY2jNHYv2iApQwQums6T7aefXotcIWxT3XI2dgyptfyombZF6bh9q6FUFX2@fHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao69cD3d0q/Hn2dbE9/Z96@7F9jWwLB1pskVWbvuWWTbrn4jSIm5ht7rm5Yhm3aXSWxoWGPDZejC@o4LTeYbVjlbzra3ZiHlLoYtzzyvRVsPL6a7Aw88nTMDjAa0xNg0eqzvOiOm2945pKRWsjN4jLayiA5dyCAgGnvtQeiewTzbHI8Nn3tCcQ2XvCFlZpn2aYxj36Hr9CZd0x4AnAH1Op74VCYv1oVgDTYOcFhGA4tTLXAwyMKRMzLm28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAWaxdzPMc9jEm3PqWPpQ7soxrFxMhY1OLWay7njMuBcUA7K0ly0zY@S8Ntlb8LeGHpuOR8wzR@Dtd51@3zDYW2M8hOBs1Iv1nBiDqzu@VrLIljAAxjagdDuH34Z687E67T5krcc6c3CQD8ozlVi3Hag@l9n6iGNDd3xBpYdoohB9x5HRvecYnp302bnjnrKO0dWx2JiYZwz6@sSCFM0@NgfggemxkQNvaESbQbYgsI91gXFjYrGlBcFkwuY1xtAxsXkdRBdo67CVz10d8MP1gnb0zRFgh@knPWbonokUC4J4ht0jzBhHtMyB0s43OjszoeNBVUxcitszXEJ9ipdhKSBKPcLV1Llr@oARWIotdmjoLjt2DUPkeGp4XX2MWDqfJCTmYAo@FkQmxNzYSO4e7CUBQXkIWR8DQrq54299FtOZXGeJdg3uuiDUYrvPHrHLRAvNnGYCEo/dlC6y@nvmKa2WAfdU7SgD9yoGscagViymOGNf0aUxZFDyIYOKjkY0SWeaPLbmEmYb19pgrttwqB60BhAB9nmGStaduC5S91ml6qdQaMuxB1CfUFh3YvMmL2ahCQD/el6GGWcG4gBvI@ecavh4CBgCfwCdoyx8wKEKhSEHumJQo2G6nmNNCA5Cej72R6gVCIox7vfZ56yvmxYGAX@MiufaNTxATgwzsXvY8iPTNnoyC7NBVMeFvngGyekQKTlAbxjN0RbKFABDQzhUVPT68Lt/0BsMIJ6tbtdxewG6fg7I3qWhUafMwuDGEGEdW7coWwCXwdR5cEjgTLfMHlE53b4IkqBMUKrnzsTqMeqo5yZ0uaEOxNYAAtH1DY7kzsSHPGbYSD/lFNHkmAsFH@kdaFhKgNKmYkvs4Q60Uhe6OeGMNJr4/TKTxrss6SkvU5vV1OZay4DMibK4nlCUQQ0QTl4nJ7Alb8Ocz7cWhgrP1z3H7MXGF/7QsTUmdZnQrTtjw04lF@JIZpJuJynKSKlTYs2sd@W@afdSyQ3AxQYknBRr3Xq3aVZPateCzycJ0ZxjNNhdjVRXFJDUUKc4U0bAXMhAyT6XAtOcn@O1scrRW55zxoq57nbGHeLEuiBeOoggQIdkzzKMcSorqyKSCYRbWm70WFbSa3EEBa6aJ@lkPJmeLzrFACVdKCh21mPTQbJljYfIb0Cl2N4YaK6LuNvVAXs8HNR8YOkyrEN4TSMhUBaiiedGEqh2BwhpiEfUJXmXw/ASEsoghlkXWuzJRm@uIwMRgL7sezeoseUgd0B5wpEHSIeNieoDaBoIzAuyxQvCUyKXxSKd2kBQMLaOwcpSx4ROgN0NaHqA83NlA/CcxmEgNt5J5mjPSL/AUY2zBrMOg2OazkZAHtwL1jWQ5gDxMfiAgolMqP95wPcyp8@yklYoLPaxG13Md5Ut6Ssg0m@VW3sSFn6@MyGhYX1gsy3dHkz0AdALx4YgerdrjP2AUEFJPB9I0fXxhhylYPCUvWEs8fB62jSIhOzRLA0k8rz1gqFQR@oSsO0S8GTI@nFZgPVMF8gSjOTXUgeAs2uJC68QZCEDr4QVWQg5AEAyY2p0Jz5QNUDg86HZHQLOYu5sThf5IHQ9eXCaTx0ou9SPksbMqI0HWkxWIifMxsooJGzRm/HA4IpRNRYcqPHnHW6PWfdGSyJ2oizCQDDnKiu6DLh3R5wjx3aWRAoVGUWLIIs@vB2AEztCphgGrpDtos4accpRE0GbAdWAng/4N/T9sVeFccL0h5OODJiiHLsX@/6Bjcii@O6F6Tvc3LGcDpBlD/qnEqagdCcdc3qtQOQWteFrL3YGDFjfY3UYud9MAOtSyb4HBJPcdxB4zksgwk1R8KcAgAQkQ0Wl@h6R4j0gKkcXdjclLCClkGEC9l1BBAMGjKrmM2TeFrP5Gpyu5xLB5jMjKwileG6XDNIcT4rRIzhlK/aNhaLdM4@xbwgCPPq65RnwtieWhdaJzalcivMKIruMfeMbQNpSlJw5Gltm1/Tb3Jc9eBDwFGwNZDxkm/rIM4kQ5huBMC0DQQGYYPjh0LLvHBGzmxKhIN@4WkjYcF3H5en6Q9c5Z@SAYLH5St1xRkjd2RfEcCEHDWKtaaN4H4ylNJTqS1mIaEwlfjmZlF87pp26TK6trSWryQaMmGtrm2DaQNMmmtJg2iSTRCaEk9FEITJkQt8mhUC3k@RVM4x5Kp5gd5jiaP/WHKf0ZrWaO8noTTV4a/gWoZ5hxABoCV8QT1Ks19EoikLjHAoqd/qLpd/BUe@o65rjoBI@0890bg9qIUfVAA3nuCgY1JB5ub1ORnUXuAsQBrrDlJtsNbOtk9Zlq5duXSUzGFqs6fUOFArSS43kgetMgA0Rm/mqpJ6IYjMHzEennswm11OpsgRiHEgi4idlMa3z2k4lDRgNU61WEio1qJ9md@hSfNOMJopRVUE@kOEBXjuVlC/LkH5HPBHTSQgrJjMgutWTSaiZLlaCR4XGvrRQQQfPv8krZiedjlH3BqkU7xvDKbih0LsY/HDy9i3SLh5HJ8Iwa6JzLm8cACj7dggro@c1oTX06vQZ0tGFND51@lwq2sHH7pO9mDGl1vr0YG/3eZ2SGereKfAU0gBhFeCVoVbcngzUwJr0jNgyGCAbYOrOcoJzB5j4oNtlksMITOryTMwNF122IjagNcR4OkyyRotF8IaQ352FMlAk5E4hb@NfumGWOPjSPEVJ7gHF3jl6sjBFNjoFfoJ1PQuZb8nlBQCrss4de/SKZIwq2ycZzQYGE3AL@MteNBdgO7aEtDAU55z5hPiECECQG3JbyEmYCzAYcd@cgkgcx/mUgPVHjhW5/x3HBuHUkL8gaigwIOQ4W2XIS/n/Q85IyV1v1juB0wfj2NK7QO8Xo2sJrAURAgVSlOU@Yu1GxNeFA5Lj7yojsFJd3cb665kkp05Mb4jVC7IEjgJuH2oVhVSc3KFa22dd4HIHUNPG1PS51Ao9/AiDPNa9lIhy0haXMxDLkEfGTIUzd8TAOl2Q8A3gldGXT5ewXfvMdB0bK1nehaiBFNWwDa5Fvqx6AY22tva1R6vrd1nkUGM3nNW5up2P9Xrldj3oXbZjOQOHrQMAoqYsc8Tet3GGE6QcXx9DjzLfUgVtDRwQ9Rdx0DCiOdNiLpI3dYRUCF5@DaMAW17oGcCKMh/tf7ULbIhayGYh/6EtS1dUyLlYrpcRHbtsBhCsAliIN9iSXxnj4YW7gE6eE8yb@DR5SB2Tz2TpwEJCroIe/paCzndy7gL9PPTqhaZlZd8lmQAn7@bl6oXSL3ArvNtACePXnNE1rIqFSG80@Kx9kXC1lAW6FU0VSP2R4@vK5zKQaHzEkEOWTCZ4SnItqUgSPgXyYlqDKT3jTEEqNYt5umt0l8Y9NYyugr44uLHQsLR6Qs8VVdOCy6YHFJO/wzqIQl4v/yCdRsJOuYvS5pmGQf54ODFiRnfoMKEFIsZ8yQQYIIYgK0tQ88AAolwSBQtWhGK@MwGxrmdY5sj092nO3rJRdpGJeMtItQLfHaA3swgOTQMYcj7hMBtkcF59NkbZAw7/HCg5xQoivsyr1DV6yvostqeO44Jc6TGV5hS0qOpHgYfieOOe7E8hAh5ql8Z3Lxznnx082m0fbh0/risTz1UsswM0ome0RyDMWtAdVlyYN5wh3AXcMW1nZEKJwijfnlrPHcfnzAMuHNzvimPAMI4nj9pP9refbz3/dpA5GtHN0cTSMY/VxDWAKI4jgrk1mq7TcYC3sCcrYwLm4mD74EkYy2cvnuxvtR/tHh4cz0XzemKZujpVxqeDVQX6DEGYKmd51R9YvcUVHRJTF2YRAmKDMleNgWzKJAmeErrxRFEqk9EDWWQcHiUJZ4F1nOd2maZmK5VeRy@XjWKvm8@X@nq/18trarnQLxe0QhYepWLFYO8IXJKMKc3cgInPiuAEEqYBmaeXKudDDgdE0S5wLBdL8xX53pK5bqFglPIVvdKtVCq6VurldK1cMoxiqZ/PZo2imu13ymo5d2vm5rKBrNXMNqIZIOh1OFlAnkD8UvBa6A4888DrnbOepmnFbqFfyWm9Qjbf61SyhXKvo5b0TsXI9vM5VVN7XU2thmFxRhWoxBAaDLlKG1jT0EtSwVOMhYPpfBPTKmO4DB0QnEQOScw4XEZGwSHwyKPHJFhExqnZwL2A7uESMk7RBO5FdB/hAvKMkyVr5BgAlgkQ15FltxM6VtAxWkFeWFsFUhnQz2X@qwMFMV@q2SuM/BzXoOfKd6mq5H7m9/sLzho5n0o4lFkz5xw58xXoxbXfoLA3vJYCR/HlKT6@cr00vhteS4Gj@Ao8PlzxXh7dNZ9loFFkRYoMV8iXxnXNYwlgFFOJYppfVZ/5lclv1ZJ6kNZS75WBorgrFDdfLW@/5qsV7WCxHLGZd5Bj4MSeOMA/PzFx3r6/0GNikQTeignhNMLiRNLMR5stkzDpbPn6jjAfEScGpn3qkOAcmdpZWS1gLFEUo1PrZsg@iBr0WAC9kambPnz8GnX69FgCgIPu9Zk58qBpz2Doh6FWV57TCydAl@VgcSp3IfmO0Z@AFKR0TBvNd4BJlTJB9jsdcxUo1ARuPgjfS8Cq7PkEJFFNzstqKPbi0gnQbD4Pe7x/QIAdnYS4xfl/tlD5/sT1IVTw/s/f6UEj3GyioX5BsmBkaNvGOeFHf2WLBUHRQo/lrTsb9aliyHRXlF0dl1x1KzIsj5paX5KGujtCkStobkBQfAAm3IJrPOd8LiZ8L0@kyqiSF9cZmG2OWHcJNMFeWxLhiZGQbTl6j6qBi8KmQYFcbGzeDMaUC4VzDA@MPKsSWrJywWZbBfzhxJ/wJ@4OuKsZzTHet3XRADJb0DuqASyy3jGNWxrd1U8nPUcCTo@KjBkrLoGdlZ4m66S@pZ9yYxuNy4vPC@iagwHwE8F7Fdj5EGQbEkqVc3rdhReePfHGUgcay4eOQzbqCqNbUnAt/lwFYgb75yLD6lozLXrco9Ej5CJ0AZaOKhq3NElzlWZeq2ZL71ygqD78eCzDBInBAZpT76bT2RwOe9Ha7/xWpNXhcayk8JXK8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyR7olab0540qKHk4dz0xLQGneRupaugeo5QfNYZxB89HjNnTHkakLYpc7M92C7LPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVdxzI97NrWKgp6fQFuliZuZ6PH3JS0uaxie8QzeUMpMi2nC07Xx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoOc2RnVaV1nXO8V7IWQ@fM4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs7t0ROl178JU3A5Ej@X1eLo0X37XWuq@2AfCKY55Ae2eeO2ZluOxI3reVi0DF4Lx53KMnq9BU7clWg@aNy8PFmRqzORglnVFu@rWwLGK5YGiw2Nl40/cPo4Jwfu@1C@iXqp6N/UK@SPHVoP3SrJ/qrind7UdLU24uGg/Z7xlBF5GwoJFydUFBEkCd@IsL9xetkwhZYXLy6sawO0Oz/WL8P0bjCyrajccWcYXxG8D@4cBKmUw@C7nwX@T1PK3p9a7H3m6EW3prkLMNe6pZcBARs8bTcq0rPqRIdRs9v7Eqm9NjImxlFYddF4buL/9Fink/pnKBsVIBLOdOCOEc50R1NtAfrxXrnEMR9utBEa3TOjkd3I6S@ndGHj0MYrch2A4RMPNgAN7Ml5o3AUpzn5@e80Nx2HPdnoLmUSfj6VI5bv5qQVG3jPovlW44sIgrm3Vc9lsNuBv5uavFyy3CV25KOxrkz8XEiaXWcozWJwNceeMy9OYTaVC05unnoSTmvejTtqqGQECrlQU27QN/wKfq5pkGbXtOI71MU0IRLdnIv8GXCku/NzVlDd4o2A3GJvNfXg4c9Lpr5r14ANSIJ1C7aHgfRs2zE@93quZJVyyhl46uGa9fR5obiL3rlRgmKfJJb51wlrNeAYzKqpclku39kjOzjodw9L5a1rM3xZfRc7dGl/EsgR8Mq1t4XoYXwGbrajGr9Gt8QVUltkDIWdojAyy3iId6L3XEy98rQSaOngv8ZZpvXFVuLEJhMLG58Jq2xwr5Ts2iGW@7g4MlGssXBUPXFcR53BWfWnl7o/0gcHPVd1GPWdTHbh1mEuDM@PySY8q33XWhWB868ftqACd6dS48ML30gifXnShPSeju6fqrvX7Lm1Uuqujy8rSxYQ7eEV76AztoTHkO4Ei26ruARjp8xNxtxUC8j8YdhnRp/ldSvM1azmWdZ@aRfrIqaXj9JfmaRfPafUg6EfFe6F3wCN43TkFCGM9VRAN@qv6zdCYwJDlOb4zNiSyrQK1cLKIP1dR0XBx5zedhbp1hgBqJHz/pvHfKZsOdMcfj@nVHlsTjx4UVKLjdcuaco@SuQ9WmD7fdsTx1hg4ne7QvCtLHUP3bfNUCWeEuPVWyXY8Vwsmkx6hs2yZUHnuhYzYUJ/3P8LX/qomDSaX@LAVGZa3cZXtTFz3AmvCdxzmWc75jD4s7p@IpnH56gMaVuUgWBlc4k3cAO6sC3eQ3bIEEiwkrkQwYsKR4ZaMLDAs6soZpYXtnXO9I5fjj1V80bXyU6bm1m8/Zko02PZAk4Pm3MwtuC/gz8Ji9NLByh5OBt5Ncscn7HvAYuFjaUtvDfBM87WG5o0KI5BuB69V9a1ZCm7fhncbWm5i3Lq6Urh1eYXgVEvSHRNebXhBG05WTptZ5tjjTyb1taUMw80l5JtQF8vF5qB9ekafr4Wg6S5Ob@S4eIgIWAqp6xpeF6fSkSJz/olTH9sZAGWWLDYDDmGXFuHmqvXS5o9GPOnLZ8ZAx@2VT0zcaWktwQqI9fri9V2Rfmuie@a3Jo5vLI3v@gL2XdE91Qdm9/FCzYeRhTUa7MHjrwW0R6eblX8@ND06vxEabplzQiTjaIt41gZ@f5m0dm26PjoYffu0yhyjFOz9ZtI@C/eIRwZcMEB/fWlay2binTHJjRdkum0S3vRpZjZ4L8Wq5ZsAbkv@fDIaT7zgtTx12qczP0U9OiV379wEsii9AWrMhrrlL5/GnpuZBZ4rGCRnxlVc@Fem5QzYV@UsAxYNBm1kypcg3DYM14e6Dz3CXoLAlPY9F0px0kNyecHeAE4YOSaZtunfPsHj@zrISOEbC8MHGzyFqDzBp/zwY2OQjpfXyJNbORgY2y@6Fh6K/1hJgJNdwMIjOrSOxujc/DzeB8kYO0GE4ehiG@fz8tqtiz5VHFIde@JLuMv/tjGleOuYUmXTcnEONVjqW7tPX4jzGELbX@/iQw0QBCeedTEzrdx4cA3xTBuYtdW0eBE6lCYeGaTS4Dlt1LwjzNYYT08RyX/kLJN4Di9g9Lm3yAQDyGT0yOjiyuOdaT9zngLrBkPZGIju6LmBWwau0ZLlATHYE6erW1A/vTuTOaJol4wVM@FaHxsdaF9rZlrOiy2L@JHu6yt4J5o4JAkwMt2JK6bVMdzXNCM4Z14l1C5m6LExJTFkNcLwXij53S5nuHFabqGPXF/b8caOY/MnEeEsvNSntxMbGB7ocf8Vdxn3Ly@MfkuFtMXSHpzx7SZGjx/cW1Vc1@g4Fn9iEVaQA9vkmwt01zQ85YlpT6bkxiTg3ZaLOXwbb1Yu4TSHN4TOdm6CjB3t7sXNanyrsHdNkgKW@Ez3aMl/uUyzsJP4/ruKhrrbdXDtLDB85MrZ3JGwO@h4tFWab03oQKNMgaDp3UmoV@COrFqjzogeK2WSuZZ@bnTwyF2Hzo/6@nQZE7l4dCxwvHZ4KyRp2PGLLHUIUo9490B2XWRbrHFzTA8i6OdL0SRM7plpdN/q4h20NOpFNJes6CTRLu1Ii5vggM2xDMkf4h5LxfdXEYxn5umkd4@1rnABZTIycM16ceVmJVI53pAwwlm@Sh8RXNcItm7jLkHo@qEZqa60tRJlMXr4H2x/psDA3C7m8QT/ZCoNgJzdvS8AMj9x7eB1H7Q7dDy/b04PxqjGyXFX0RcsVgGCwIt3BzStryoEtKc9sfh8x2BuR9eoR/IdcIN9B0wWkXDfkAz7TCIVR1OMIzj/QapqIqUGXiY4mQRuphucfvbkUO9SnE5xUacMzxOwOCpemOD8ARRMZgSXSunptCjGeCDc2zGwASyEIsUxqFSC66TxGDBgPsGafdZsssTltJqtqleszoSqwE5OeKx4kYqD3emYtL4858GbCf2knkhKUjKRbNlVlk1G4IYFgsdScH0Btm/Si@d3VgVcI5RD6pyiEte40gwgCKiQZqjbPctgL2xacANu0eWqH7hekWPcSPrLP@4FenpIH9XI9HQLKgRVbTkjY@icb/J0g9SBj9JRzw/GATKkxbVOSDtbDAQYvzvk6nmcc/Zi77gcKP0I9HqB5ZBPA0W54I2La1F4gNHnjcdzEx1GCxKOQoWFAs54MrJhKOr5Q09mRyadTZy4s9MGgbYz23dxwrmXYfusZ@CePTpySusrluOc0jEUzMkv/5irOqGDp8GBwDB5UnE0lyKeL1VJv0i360wg12Ekbw3XCUBSWMkgNU5wNZM0bJG7iMcxSQcLYKQUaiChZLgakp2tIybtsiTq7kKNATWzn0psPf/082b2pP6ejRTjP39HES@DihM@kSpFT8iwEKR2hYg1710A75lvkgmJqcATjE7lmgHve87bA/WOcSTDg7khjjnOOOg1pEWKlCZF2BgoI0ihmdo5VEUyIgVUhLDGOakioeNfNhJCUoDmQQcDq0hR815XT6QmfIFNOvJZARJEdS46mLjKKjqnimo1MEhiyt6xISIZcFNqIQs2XpEWanIZ1bfDHd25@Z32yiOjM6HdpmearBXqVJxEu77RIBNQawc1KjVftqZaVmpNS7snwB8GldpqTT/Jal9CrTsuhHqgYM/bffboMiE3su/eefoFE4SrZI2fDAAykbg83D/cPTreOn5xBK1wFZKfPX4@KKQ1iEV05G/oWKSrCuoFGbWPoD@RDTVHpFhCZxuoDVEUY/OHswg0qGtBEhLcOEeaFkLfEXxZeM@Y878JENC0vslCjNqHQRrbEJANaw0LPxmjxi0WhA20BhGWmUjjsQNFFYPnL5bQUqoqgdWhsiSorHtWFVtd2E3udp8auzOW26ttcykI1liUXjPy50VcWgVX/yDlHsNA@d9ebh7L7eUmmFvKDaCRaxhmb2v/yYvnu4vBAMfoTVS3XikEpxI5ccaexpm9UE0SKQMIAuICZV1gAgXg1mAw48oaDf/cgGIFxLE74oEJQyn/QmyGmFAzddQXelLjdZFKUQ6QB6lhsa4dmgRObC6L4Rg9F90lL2JEBPaEKOow47IQxBwnvZcyXmExMNagusKud0hEPKDXSW@e/cmEPQ6LhmP0xON9bsVQFY06HoP/3KgUmrQTNmXBcKaeMIlpcFuGPYACh7BijY9RLMErQkjwvAtRflFfIeSp91qnNQE6DBAcNoRR2tLHqBwtgH7m@EaVvZk4pNAgJCYRf0GqMnWuXpSalivNJEUJIISB7BCOWxTf/t5RHbkzzpoRfZ/HuYmNAxUAcU2fwZFj30WNuPwsKFe5x6vcCbS7hUMlydVeoM0p4hI8dmZ6JkiF1Ah95HEsoJRYmqDgqC2WVFmwLcsDnqQHwzdwKD4OtcCcyHRCjR9Tk2wmxAEn5YhlzDAhhrBe/aa2LxhKz1FOeMUDJwiOYvbm4kxurEkS1NzAtEPVsFXUFUsiZZX57gQ3oDWSN4KEWaiSSRr6I2sOcInew5ahfPjdP@C6Dls@mH8QmKfZbbD9dmDrg/l3Qh9VBds/i2wa2H7IbS8VbLKbCt5m@YzO6q880wfI@VC4UTAkDKGSXCpQ1OTY3J/vHzKvi7pXsUFHIOjP2grJDCIeCHyAhCPAjDNqaATnKczacRZPqvk54AkgFyAJ8jjI1lB6hnuSQl1fVUXBjONSgUw7AY0pX50n1V9vJqjyEjgxpVgo5lUFMimdhRGSNpIBHkziEYpiFQhj7Mwc1191umxjY4MJXle3jHqxxhFESegvc8KrKKMJgI1xaaHJIAwEmYUAv0YQLJXQ06qIQXE0S6pJJGw9h@MbsIQpMgCIiM52qL8AeE4nqCpAZtuY@sQ2XYRSEFBt25nTdRtGJEFEPG5UzHi9T84OG@H81lwvleebQfgCwY4QrCosw9jmS9byW/ZJoKCTAfb9dAn@2mD@J0u0dnLMQv0sN9VFpq4re8TSsIdHtoPThHuQW5bSFC2nqEVxDkOFICrIL/b3dxAl9HCgGF3DfO2Mva2d3f3PDg6PbqgNIsjkdbAkSzY20i1JzjRPIkMyyvdipW7vKUdPt/fCqpzP1WyiDiFmOy@vZ3NZatdzuiL1L/i5rptpk8eNhNTsfSOmbU3SHu1gvhn7zFeZA9zhx0pupJoSL6@aJxuNlh2/kfy7Zapg4/I6IheYWh4pgk1ezyZmMVL7foxq3z05PLSs4ollPMrmO6ez88@Bw5wHBw9jAQoQk5UQahXxhAwc8EmamaIOjeud94j08YkcUtAZ5WgO8jjUUI9da6ZXLlCoNtS9oWV2YjCA91DJIFeHEur7iBSpyN7YMv2UGKMpkDqyQUDEUoGe@ml1KtP6YorUwVJcGXabjrYwPjEGnQDiSx5OvCE7dMZsNv/0yAhNz4EbYY8mfPHJYJ9NRgDXp9dzA0msAfyJBIGhopJRVrlUDT0rUNE2TaMaPEiviYragoLLo14hNRXloTHtmQMg4CkxAz39ExXYqugQORaa1LbZSaBxvIY/xeM881X6UZr6prPI9aYum3bPmKZQ9Uz1BPhTdE@ef3GWFIUbOEDqAndCBWPX9AaGHVH3gx4x07l3rbNVIuX01xQ7ViqovgfPw0OzQIpHvvsEjDA@pfojfcxSE1Jo6TGZkTXVStkZz3dFJjW4TgybpdMkVcOLPIBrRtA@mQhxWAr1P6eUOrQOunp2D19vzTFrqrJ8AmZKRGQJnFHbgaEc56LEGEhJEKRK0daxbVkVc8SxV@aYB2HQP0YathhqdVziTXoYafrWwbqgUrPGgznNRLMeyGu1UqkGrbFIaioM0OImlZcViHYJCQm5VKjf4Hgz1BrqKUeF9ji7DWTh4TcN2zagggBnRjqMwfoEkMwVM@GHKTIzvdaUQpxn8XFwXhoyuqjvejd5aeESaEKp0eRM7QrG1FctHFT7wbB6ofyPiqzULlMJq36hAKMjNlKJYV1N59bT6YS9nkrYONQ/eIBzOlcJ4CTaMohIUwCSEpZYA3wGzqOesGsJfSOV6NW1dQoBVhDSLiHAe0@RLxP6lZJ4ACN1Blxc3nlTCY9UJmZlWb2C/GEPSSgZwJlL1DBHX6XA5BNmOo15kBNtzMB7pXWUJprdOlJo@qgWcKPKYBR0t2tUNWqJG9/k4BUYOAcNDYRdQ8IebFNvh8Azbde5ZX4reA@e8DfxJBCjzYeGN8/@C4s@9ycsAb1LkjYrrqCS66yECpymoBLRmtFFEYjJr38dV4tMSCU2i7mzdLKQrcFDrZVYgX2SaGn5OIs/BHFdWRdc4bL1qHzGjL5WfCNJTb0vvzk5PD08/FJspZLxnYOXgpoH0BKr0H3fq8S0FRf7uCseX1dicWVdfVBSlFevXgG7C1ezITfmoeQTsSklT5qpElgapdJ6plhezzxMtikrYkrTxCNmmgprmWOv14PbGdK3YVJxfrHNTUwLDPBngdto2udus8xwkMA1DBt63QVX1Qtx1irp@no6rz20a7KW1X75i7WrzOVhe@OX3x0pxhq@DvD1g6unaD5SC5@srX2yvZ3PZ6DyuPnwq8Nvb21t5R9lCofNwmZeyq5t/NVfrK1p2oamrJ14nnqSbJ5@KWjZvCD/8ufJw8NvtT0P2w@vHFPBiM8y3CorFNgpewvXaZ/hn8xve3NmHc2d/lscIIFZrhOxSSYLueTRyyQW921cVdX4Bf3aVA1rTG1slv7Ljw7exP14Q1O@cOHtx9/Ei@U4N4IBbLnQdhZvxDcQrHgVv1Dq9ToYS//l30H4xmcQD/pcbMCjUQjjKl7EG1KdgryLN4pgUDUN0v1/vvOdWLwxRURo7O8xraGtc1xRyw/UB2zKL9aKq@X8wUNwDq/QK7qYoqpaK2zPuebGpo2ch1B4aFfmzLlF7R5iRpwF2ECGj4HDzwgV1x6@esQ2GjDU4lWtPoxQTWGlsuA40J1rYHsSuT@XJbjkdmivoVUKihAv1zNtnnyEq/E5w7UCR08WlD2yfyTcLl5//X/99Y//@kf0@zHd/ykWDzcISM2zxkkjvJjQQPrEAttTmz3ll23DH@7Qii7oACabzcoSjzca@KB/YCMTva@5BT6NyEIQsyC3wAU0g9KNxd9DmyD2sbPGwsUaCovMVASeazI8nSvZrGyIAptwrcGP/nBFVnyukUvgTCA3rzXWuO26lfrG4s148@SkSp3p/hdbHnf8LBaXgDSk08@BZwyQ@T7XC7hluR3YIqSOx@L/oFcjxuKXcJ2kpaurpvwyXasFf2ClapENL26CPJ1cSdLGy0Y63aS8NRtBJjekk4bM2jy/9Hi5AfGmN5obdWeHbrmNdSQl806y6Dw8edlobizGEUTz8GEaO/NDiKeROGHAxEPNXm1cNa6aG1dXGxvw36DnVfAG16uNG396za7aCqDoujrBRm81lUZLaQUNegJ2WWmgi6y0wNCAdxsAm81Y/BLxhTVPSMtWXWqqxcKJxKhPrFfRr@sxVlXXtZxSmH5S3NVicU0QlHX0eocjE/AXlVgcufQKZ9Yr5PDqw9f/B96tD1//G7BC1vBrZuTbeYO/J2/x98bH33EXf8/f4O/4Lf6e@/g79PD3tIO/WLzOGDBHic2slT3LqqfqKRhMlgXedJgdqj0cDLIGy15kL1h25Kg9MBnwy4LJzPZZdsCydtZWVfAEg8@yPpr68BrArw@xuPAzs1mMPHvGIBULhxhSTkvvd20mtmJNJrwygKuR1aScTcrFZNI8KRTHb4RMst1qJk9qccVrtRTO7zEtXyOtxFdXrN3effao3VawB7SeOgez/8HBaN5663904Dw9cEYO/A8ODp5Ce6cfpqWHcNUb6Y3gtRlv1DZbVQnRWA4QOq5sbLYaOQnNxTQgp4Zu6Y@8ZjHCu7HWioEw/MUX57UvvsD/@VntvEaGyAqGdi0CCMC4ARy5A0TwRa1GBjTDdUaxkg2N51@0IhM3KF@cg9MXDNjz6K8s2P4B/ub/v/5PX7BU80SEfnB5tZGiS8SfKF5eXV4Fz4aYSgWW1Ab80AHsGOTyqoFGAroEUzMlnohXV9wNnilxg0fYwDQ2GhR4Bgi0Ih6lSenyR@of9o1p86uVBP4I5NZUsOjWak2zWbHWAZdo5l1/R@s3Yo12tiQ6uOYGspoqEkQhX6up69ys5bVaLR9YSuVarRyYE6lU5ebVyG6qxWJVy@dFsVbLBrAgltVCI0RheHq3ht27Fh@LmFve6VNZnPyjTxEkharw4EEq@HjF5ngMYrpayb57Fzm12z3TbbfRPffundAWcBdMvVIAe7b87h0QnqQIAvwzh6@/piSVfaI1KIUKSOZavgTeTFW0WZpD3dN93029NccZATegeYJI6oOzWcdtJX/1w@9@t5Ws474Ics2rGAGmwgobG8V8o1HMg7lYhpILCb7RJjVIV1TxKqEIvLwggCfjgZdaLonkepVEfxbfYJsN6KgeXuzyKk4NyPIFMdW5MMRLcAnd1EqFO7J8MVVOV4JffU1kjXUW/JrNZi6dXy@tPzw5ObnG7yMxrV3qdfWqfqlXcXboqtYN9NPjmRD9wYNcBWqxnK21Yu32o63jrTZ@2g7XvmHkY@hIZDmG65pjN9mkqbxC5aSJJTppJZPV2kNqcLVcYPFkLYCTkkDhWblCBY97Xszs4@GwKcV67V6Pj5laysGQGhvTHqRSlvVwGddlTr@/Bo7QYqyDK@6eYVmhQv9zx7V652bPWIvFD59s7eweZ7QNGJ21va2djHb0YjuuorUws5N3Du3Pd7ceHbyAAIdPdreOdj/d/3z3xSG4e7HXb3XD0I2JYZy3J5PzN6jz3WgbY3CdXW2ja3r669f6mC5W4wT5/PzDT7//4af/04ef/fDDz77/4Wc//tXXP/4@3H8M9w/5@4f/tlLA56@@/md/9OEPfwaO/wnu/wj3L3719e9/h99k/3O4/3LO7c@Dew6O36wab6zjBYhQ1srpdRjx1isVQAZy3YhBWr/9q69/9PNfff07P4H7XwT3T27ev/uL5fePv7f6xnA/@qPbYX747@D@Ex5XCPvDP@Ru@L4B/4cc7nd@8uH3/j3//1XwQ@PPPvzen@MjsPzTn/zVX3747n/QtPJf/esP3//hh@/96MP3vvvhez/48L1/rH34/X@tZucff/Thx3/6X//sT/7rn/0v9P9jev7Jff4ffvJP/@b//Jv/@2/@LLh/Afe/B9Mv/uY/ABr/3Z/@FP8/@tO/@48/xf///i//7k//17/77X9Fhj/ghv/3X/xb/vzb737/b7/3z//2u1@veH7/1ufX93D/@r@Dy/3zeZ947lOuj3X5@jfKz39LbcxSARwg5ftMA6Z2@8JgNRbLsmzwgE7443/y4fd/C3D79wASbP8z2ODPLeD1A7J8@eWCX5rmOKT0l1@CcPhlICR@OQ/0A8beKcCAZx@@A4AvyZdfLIKCRP83hAIwFkCFYAuJEwjun@TOv/r6n/8c3aOQ6Ppb8/FlQ9c52AQCvwuL@APszFEx5mF/gOTgw0@/8@Hn//jDT//gw09/G8cCKV/JbGVgDL99BhUAC/eAQ8DifeAAUEUBEST5tZgGhrUNnPGLqelXr6AR1sAE8tV6rJADW0xtkFlFMwQEuX@dIpmmcZIE7mksXwEbGMBpSgbwSoPXdho/tJyOTevgR6D4hWaGxkYZZ@twCqEO8WIgHibTLoPMwqbbFAuErKefs/Z6fcoDptGhQTEwzBA6PRdUTUiX648gwfr0EcO4MPJ07BW8X9Ub5fq0gdG9pyxAHOltSBKg8APQ6WnjPdjrFCfAx6aP3kNWyvV0ulEGlzoVlVLLtClNtUCFo7KnGZUb3RnDPYybDxn7RFDLAp/jgKpkATQ@0zPoTZoC3AT/Vno9KA79QyPd6xge2mlK9cPduP8mOlP4AADilSTc@ga3JGFuHoL3lEeVpmThleYxQM2l@RQpixyIQUnH0tS@abJA@pCHj7k2@OCM0WFxEokEmDYaQk5oH4CoyNzTqufrLi7MEb9YZUKxIqAz7iLi@yMThyRRrj9ah6cK/9012hNMJamtxxJJnKBIsjAlKZ1z8k6cFyIsIdnWqQBpAmSfgA/eDx@CGWqI3jO3WHwWjgsZtAbL1GKeibEUfU1IpFkQA5kgFnvqDbadKfD3GUHIqEVcWxH5HEns2061Wn@v5ksxeJN9gt8xCr6oA42FX3OWNzaw0huXEk3XoBEYw2Ks0QgWkZkaaxztHgP48QFTtazMQBq4zJe0fCFf0HLFYqGkqfliJV8slHNAyorZgqaplXy@Uq6UrqgsD4EaZKrrncJG4x/duP6Hf7TsWu6KV6zxJZvKNBd9FWtYdb6RMYGLyUIrK9Ro2ohqLtHMZvCn5XLwhDxm1ELpZG3NupSwyC3aPXeJy/WQzdilhHPf34CLxb4RY98AJ7ggDVxOY8EGiP2DWrDYjZ8i5AvegloA3BFjLcAdHhs04uXl5dwdi6999ZXPGg3g66X9vVgccH7IwtVdyezJQ5k@INibuAb5Dhh7tP/5/tH@wTP50f4R8NrfZlouK8fiV1dX/WhNgqwGOzg4iCGxAckpp2L4qy6bTCbk2wH71VSPjeev2ngc0zRJy0k5VVJz@L/DoOH//vAa/DV8QqicFmOx9@/fT2mjQHXf9oMdA1q@jO4shjj@AOj3A5UbC8WZMYvGjeB4eSNGC6NNwK@TGH6LqnkS21Aiz2M86f8MGgow22ZPcH@w77Bjh@9D3Ta6KyB2hvyr6juuA2LTbw6zrdun3OuRyY8cR16PddQ56o1Mf7gC4sV4hKfmDPe/Wwy7ow5kEJdIOMA2PFzLcZYBlNiLwxWlfBppCME9CKQiBMCf73/6@Hjufby7tfM4VmTbB88eXXsVAqACe7K7dxxZS9w3DFqIovj27pMn163BC8hljeTkNVYoZTIw6sAD3xm66C0nXoYgqryaHdF9HaTwJsuf1GDwL9c2VZwXKSSUunr4BAV4yzl0ga62UBx/L218Xm/oiT5Q5vq21Ci/T@dL5Zx12dgd4qdW3ZprTP2BsWZP2AsQ/GNPcS9kReUHe0wv9hhk7hF@0Ak/3ubH8JByDz/ajHMqHfx68mTMVjrCC53Q6JqDIQwQ504IEOvoOoP7Yy8IPy9uQ33d6uDzNMjtho@1BBwX4M0@y8ZkmoTWKuVCuZLTyplypZwvqMVCIaNqGbVULlWAWGfVslosFypqppyv5PIwmoBvoVKKxYHKmn1FgZFSFQR4VyFau4vfINjAjzk48rARi/OZLPY2pYvQsJF9wgQDwgj4NSzPp@3e62Zd0PJ4FiOnMohRZ10W39vbye7tCcI2WnCyfScrCD20FMrZbGlbEAzy2YERTxMEh4cBLwDzuSWb3d4RhAmPADWaCMIQLbtFZOEFwUTLztbeHqbzGi0ahgewU@7DLVZoKQGYjZZcjmQAQXgTRQdwWzyhPOV0Fy2YJvrscZ8d8BOET8P8ZLMQw3MOx2N4HJZ1a0sQ9rllawt9PqOCF3hWv4mWLboEwQULIKEgDMAwcA3DFoQOGBEVBaELpu6FDm74vQfUcmH7uiBc8ArCKhKEKUHr3VMBeNXAHZN5/PixPvR7xoBfFy5/dyFr4GNOJ7t7nU8/7QwGHfdia/fT5@jz2WeP9dcXE7cz6ATBOm24HAgDPqeji@sX5HG/3datpT7fBB/7mk/7om1g3tr6G8hTcA0wkVH7M/D5DHymSy4eG1wjAO3gtT2C97beIZ/wIh96TzsdoYaI6l@MDZzEwz5DX3XPjPSu69TQPq2vJVPJzEWzmD2pkTMbpcTLbO0Kffsp@qIgkkTx8qI5rWdPQH4pacF5kZTQmmoFU8isjTaBylXX9E1Vy6enVVRX6/STLCmpmyn1wfrb1DNxU8vlq0Jrc1MSmurJpqaWq8XSy/WJIIhVfG7mStW3qWwyyxg@xGbpZLNUmAtRKqV1RauWSmLtCmrCh3GpM/GNdjuVOjf0U1HEvCJTAPnnH6@/oCKatX5qmpnWeabYhVib1tUaP2fNsjfi6qGijwl@tovHOIDoppvZKlLslKBWygKkrygpUURqhPQD3q@@CBd2otecYcHIL5lVJf7NP7VcFGU8edB2@m367hF7NQ@JHHXsCzwmREeEw918JHt41dgxMuA4AOgMlQl18DOjdGYe5D@unIbx6Q21VInFGgEPesi/uFILrJ8@3pGBLQ1sqDJE3sOvSzuujF9F9Rd8uDqL0OkYhij5sYF79Lqh2w4/vCvvTkHCwAMKtUvpC@lqPsQRsNo8DTy/UKOj/ngSGHWnmD2m1xtg0nssRekzXTyncrYbjXq7PjJGY/8CBB@@PAylCoM/m4zYNuOweKwoPFTRrm9DBWRrNuoPM9CamMansUYPtaNs17cvJ1XkKa9qRp2@nS3E8SjWpl2f2J7eNw4NF08B7R/AWG3gcZvu8FVrFwF3oLIvr6SGy@xZIfY9XkfRmQ7K0CVmKPBo17NXtflcp3Sp0RFrg3oTQd/hY0MShBNJar47AXmqFmtA76tdxPW6N@nwD8xlOyBKFWtTcFNL@dqQdeqdl9OaWx@DBMBqFtTinGDD9BrBv7NgIG3L7fp0Vhu5elMD0SabCYUdDbd4ZbRsJaOpMJLCCAsh4S6BPQ@3Cjf4qygKpayUwJiQyU6zsppRDTUDkuQrs/dKzPjOrg0tkq1WsWGgUckKb52JaW3dSvUcpm9I1MbQxWuUcT0zZGMTHikI99zQLQogihJLSW82i@lCVhRrbyDXbiLVk7fFzXytl9pmbREcgDeAW2PFfK1fT70UF@tYrKXWxLpnvKH6RFJBlTFeg@YIxD1vMmpm2VpRzVxKbenK0j0/oZa0anOSaEoqlDb7brAhfNUQTqBprhgIJWx@XQZYjxq4hWSBMyszdmPmNkaO0zKgFdWKVgtAYuOASKWEFH58mO8oTSWTJS2ZFJM1nFhYA/eAyBFFSgJ5TD5QNwVgd4SqUNFAjJwjbjeywJfyiiDhXcV6pjdm@Uosfhm7urzamN8k8012caGnpdD6gLFBOhFjCi2Uy@04WyOTJDdo9mervjV4vlULoLd2YvEq7Qibbd9hreAIrqSsfezqfHqj8ZK/W7ghBVKNkb6cJjsJtiNoOShzb84O5fMuY7xW@T4NZSPdUFoxQaC@zZf4ygWR55S9j5PqebZz2Q@IUvUpypcspVd5n22eiO@fmdZlOSc1SIBMsfj7NNQIbm5rKO/jMCxcUUUHW8guL8eXlyA8X@Gxci1XiMVtJ9xdBmKpD2QQxpNCQcC5FoONjyovSy/LL5@@OHhxsMceZqvlanleuGg9zGTUpJrcYA@BjTWf74Lg8o45BfW9/Rntq4vX4tVxMpdP5haC1ePTej5cxE2pjYakbmhsE3CVVYFC9dWilH3X4IjXII@iBj4ffusn@elGGewasIpVqNNCWms01HVNjI8/fP1v8KTW5e7nW09YEgv493/xc63093/xL2nhMHlV44UuxQESjWqxFD@J8yzkS0wEC1@@VuMNJXBXS6oY9yRug@wV4t67QHFGSsuWwW/ngNuEItRavBKPxctPX71jbAMkyEZvMDA1MinKglSWqIKkBX/2Huen3ktrr4CeeF5CwR2NFQQOJ1XWG43GOm10TDbSeMJQK9BcfvOqdsInPVAOWbfpZ3jr@DNeRg7rngf20AbW9Q2DFRoqA8FFUT781u9rWvHv/@J3W@K79rv2t4DCViqVoqrFf33zigeKfDTIi2Hz3a5VPKsrlfm2fSTcrz3@VfDwyCJ9ERo4ZFLN4tFnRS3TPoUAyBOAGb81CkxEld3zfGQsGLLf4oGdwNzRPaOYD23ehYdbzXE6EM8relVFGZj@cNKhA4rH7sW@f0DHNxTAFxPEfTJ3LKejjHScZqAPTHkgRAEE6iOf2AqMk3j6gj7AiXwraqJok64kKFqvDWBtLFZKrMYYpDzG09Stab8v0DFsw@odGWOddOKAf3hWdb@HYKgxiQ55h@eLF3iq6HAx1bjBkjt8j71Ep8QdYmW8ZHiukKqWkQYLA099CHjOOTitRNvnBRlt@E1lIdw6DxB9B5WmhvD02eVZgOgrzLMQWEZUshJwDvX5ErE0lT8dZgInjLkD5WNmDRKdOVBClBuXmRndHZA2MBv1KUFaKWhWGZVDNtXqSYbzmnWV6puOs5tso86AgUelLVQSrFBSkdk3XWDX1PKcOhdi1ijkfDnS9SAnAMgbBI9voyosPIzgdF6T@qdAswTinxz6BSf6Ud8WGnFWxg7UwrLzjukTAAxtBIAhlQEe8@FVlFlA1c5kgOcnsC/IjjtQTM@bGIVSOU8Z0vFQdggK7O0CqKYEuqoVyhyegY5KUfGHzDLODIu0DATZRsWBOu@UhGe4Uwb1ICKTXhQJdaAqF0oKtZCqZLjbo929J1vHu48yTFILCI6H2LpOBJuaq1zunSb/vjXxhgEaYRDefeVOMc@RPOVlkg@VpBhk/eF8tafnMxxGgJ@UwjnBcSpZp2CuMcLvd/GI2VjvIa3KUBg7GRzUxxPy/CCY6WFWJq6FeBNWbtjz43EBURrTiiMKLnxDHsJgwQLeBmxAeG4AraQVUAMBdWv7gJGohoQwV1h2oh0IqyQ1uJ4FYcfCD/olUavVPLVNUt/RWfIYlYnDkE6kbS1JdAE1OQzryU@8ZK0LbHvIU7Cz1ES8DEpg2n3MRYpX3LGzfRG2X2oSHLERoEJEYIzF6MzNL/8yCXxGFJ9npXzx8kx32ds6YCj1OJkT9V2LjjKmklzHLAR7KyPPERxtq/u1KEDH6V3IqELP7u0MTauXejufxhhYTbOfSqe79XpOvIQk3TEQJ28MxNBAYU6soVt/wQ0spBAnpbRaNuRPXreNc/bl0yePocmfG3RyvfnyZD2hZIC1FWtYBL2eQqBHB08PddczXFEe43svEptS@AmOIBEZWnvkNbMnlPuMgEVTsBcC5RwYflB6b/viWB8800dGKqkn@ZkxTMqERjE3dJnLRzUznRahiHrTPFmoo7qw2LiCeDmoE9TQNfq1DlT0ae3Kq5@lBmLNh9dwPokCJFHXNIrdh0B1Dx7Xat3ED3I/Pn76pJ7c0BnGWl/SK5LpToQcgCiEMHQYfst19YsF1AGqQljl82OfhDBwpZNCY7EsG4reSALLujI/TxxSViHLcnKGwL3UJBNgnFu/2aQ1d4YFF2Ojjg58aPt091jIQFh3YojoaOPwdkFEi2s0qIdpcHRDSkFD4MURwtTr@QcPyI1rM6nXtWxWBNSsXUFsHmBuKhJ73NqVq9d7qagi9bG5RHuCJmuKbnvnqFcbWN5sobTpuDBE1HvAQz7wgITUUXf0melfPPAA2@qhJoYH/EhpfS2/Xj4wt7/1ZeWo@CjV7XymChnhtefYIKK54/kMuPq5zNkioLFul2MXZQJ1bHZ1ZayfOkq@l@2Ws2W11DNKBaOczZW7BSNX6QCX2O3ny51epaSXCt2OAoObT0HkkYmffBI4@mOy/fslu4oxK4PI3@@rwK33CpV@RcvmcvlOudDL5vP9sqrncsWeVu5UOrdzbbP8oLgV0l0cO65T4E9WM3exG7Q9CC3@fw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
 
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1PLconsloPrs  \puts~-<V=>a$f 16=B->8~+4783l{>Ehar Cr;rextge!nu Ule.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

I use literate markdown Granule with [`literate-env-name`](https://github.com/granule-project/granule#literate-granule) changed from `granule` to `x` for golfing.
Command line: `/opt/granule/bin/gr polyglot.md --no-info --literate-env-name x`.
I don't use empty `literate-env-name` because of a parsing bug that treats any `~~~` or ```` ``` ```` on a separate line as start of code in this case, 
so adding another language supporting literate markdown would be impossible.

Granule code is on lines 137-140:

```hs
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~
```

Space before `=` is mandatory, otherwise `Premature end of file` error.
Granule doesn't seem to have a way to place multiple statements on one line, `;`/`,`/`.` don't work.

Answer (score 3):

## 249. [Oration](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/oration), 11584 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWmp771zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@yFbemjTk9nAGG4Y9fwKfoCgyi6pxRm0afI2FPH9QxMvmt4noOOJcY2jNHYv2iApQwQums6T7aefXotcIWxT3XI2dgyptfyombZF6bh9q6FUFX2@fHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao69cD3d0q/Hn2dbE9/Z96@7F9jWwLB1pskVWbvuWWTbrn4jSIm5ht7rm5Yhm3aXSWxoWGPDZejC@o4LTeYbVjlbzra3ZiHlLoYtzzyvRVsPL6a7Aw88nTMDjAa0xNg0eqzvOiOm2945pKRWsjN4jLayiA5dyCAgGnvtQeiewTzbHI8Nn3tCcQ2XvCFlZpn2aYxj36Hr9CZd0x4AnAH1Op74VCYv1oVgDTYOcFhGA4tTLXAwyMKRMzLm28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAWaxdzPMc9jEm3PqWPpQ7soxrFxMhY1OLWay7njMuBcUA7K0ly0zY@S8Ntlb8LeGHpuOR8wzR@Dtd51@3zDYW2M8hOBs1Iv1nBiDqzu@VrLIljAAxjagdDuH34Z687E67T5krcc6c3CQD8ozlVi3Hag@l9n6iGNDd3xBpYdoohB9x5HRvecYnp302bnjnrKO0dWx2JiYZwz6@sSCFM0@NgfggemxkQNvaESbQbYgsI91gXFjYrGlBcFkwuY1xtAxsXkdRBdo67CVz10d8MP1gnb0zRFgh@knPWbonokUC4J4ht0jzBhHtMyB0s43OjszoeNBVUxcitszXEJ9ipdhKSBKPcLV1Llr@oARWIotdmjoLjt2DUPkeGp4XX2MWDqfJCTmYAo@FkQmxNzYSO4e7CUBQXkIWR8DQrq54299FtOZXGeJdg3uuiDUYrvPHrHLRAvNnGYCEo/dlC6y@nvmKa2WAfdU7SgD9yoGscagViymOGNf0aUxZFDyIYOKjkY0SWeaPLbmEmYb19pgrttwqB60BhAB9nmGStaduC5S91ml6qdQaMuxB1CfUFh3YvMmL2ahCQD/el6GGWcG4gBvI@ecavh4CBgCfwCdoyx8wKEKhSEHumJQo2G6nmNNCA5Cej72R6gVCIox7vfZ56yvmxYGAX@MiufaNTxATgwzsXvY8iPTNnoyC7NBVMeFvngGyekQKTlAbxjN0RbKFABDQzhUVPT68Lt/0BsMIJ6tbtdxewG6fg7I3qWhUafMwuDGEGEdW7coWwCXwdR5cEjgTLfMHlE53b4IkqBMUKrnzsTqMeqo5yZ0uaEOxNYAAtH1DY7kzsSHPGbYSD/lFNHkmAsFH@kdaFhKgNKmYkvs4Q60Uhe6OeGMNJr4/TKTxrss6SkvU5vV1OZay4DMibK4nlCUQQ0QTl4nJ7Alb8Ocz7cWhgrP1z3H7MXGF/7QsTUmdZnQrTtjw04lF@JIZpJuJynKSKlTYs2sd@W@afdSyQ3AxQYknBRr3Xq3aVZPateCzycJ0ZxjNNhdjVRXFJDUUKc4U0bAXMhAyT6XAtOcn@O1scrRW55zxoq57nbGHeLEuiBeOoggQIdkzzKMcSorqyKSCYRbWm70WFbSa3EEBa6aJ@lkPJmeLzrFACVdKCh21mPTQbJljYfIb0Cl2N4YaK6LuNvVAXs8HNR8YOkyrEN4TSMhUBaiiedGEqh2BwhpiEfUJXmXw/ASEsoghlkXWuzJRm@uIwMRgL7sezeoseUgd0B5wpEHSIeNieoDaBoIzAuyxQvCUyKXxSKd2kBQMLaOwcpSx4ROgN0NaHqA83NlA/CcxmEgNt5J5mjPSL/AUY2zBrMOg2OazkZAHtwL1jWQ5gDxMfiAgolMqP95wPcyp8@yklYoLPaxG13Md5Ut6Ssg0m@VW3sSFn6@MyGhYX1gsy3dHkz0AdALx4YgerdrjP2AUEFJPB9I0fXxhhylYPCUvWEs8fB62jSIhOzRLA0k8rz1gqFQR@oSsO0S8GTI@nFZgPVMF8gSjOTXUgeAs2uJC68QZCEDr4QVWQg5AEAyY2p0Jz5QNUDg86HZHQLOYu5sThf5IHQ9eXCaTx0ou9SPksbMqI0HWkxWIifMxsooJGzRm/HA4IpRNRYcqPHnHW6PWfdGSyJ2oizCQDDnKiu6DLh3R5wjx3aWRAoVGUWLIIs@vB2AEztCphgGrpDtos4accpRE0GbAdWAng/4N/T9sVeFccL0h5OODJiiHLsX@/6Bjcii@O6F6Tvc3LGcDpBlD/qnEqagdCcdc3qtQOQWteFrL3YGDFjfY3UYud9MAOtSyb4HBJPcdxB4zksgwk1R8KcAgAQkQ0Wl@h6R4j0gKkcXdjclLCClkGEC9l1BBAMGjKrmM2TeFrP5Gpyu5xLB5jMjKwileG6XDNIcT4rRIzhlK/aNhaLdM4@xbwgCPPq65RnwtieWhdaJzalcivMKIruMfeMbQNpSlJw5Gltm1/Tb3Jc9eBDwFGwNZDxkm/rIM4kQ5huBMC0DQQGYYPjh0LLvHBGzmxKhIN@4WkjYcF3H5en6Q9c5Z@SAYLH5St1xRkjd2RfEcCEHDWKtaaN4H4ylNJTqS1mIaEwlfjmZlF87pp26TK6trSWryQaMmGtrm2DaQNMmmtJg2iSTRCaEk9FEITJkQt8mhUC3k@RVM4x5Kp5gd5jiaP/WHKf0ZrWaO8noTTV4a/gWoZ5hxABoCV8QT1Ks19EoikLjHAoqd/qLpd/BUe@o65rjoBI@0890bg9qIUfVAA3nuCgY1JB5ub1ORnUXuAsQBrrDlJtsNbOtk9Zlq5duXSUzGFqs6fUOFArSS43kgetMgA0Rm/mqpJ6IYjMHzEennswm11OpsgRiHEgi4idlMa3z2k4lDRgNU61WEio1qJ9md@hSfNOMJopRVUE@kOEBXjuVlC/LkH5HPBHTSQgrJjMgutWTSaiZLlaCR4XGvrRQQQfPv8krZiedjlH3BqkU7xvDKbih0LsY/HDy9i3SLh5HJ8Iwa6JzLm8cACj7dggro@c1oTX06vQZ0tGFND51@lwq2sHH7pO9mDGl1vr0YG/3eZ2SGereKfAU0gBhFeCVoVbcngzUwJr0jNgyGCAbYOrOcoJzB5j4oNtlksMITOryTMwNF122IjagNcR4OkyyRotF8IaQ352FMlAk5E4hb@NfumGWOPjSPEVJ7gHF3jl6sjBFNjoFfoJ1PQuZb8nlBQCrss4de/SKZIwq2ycZzQYGE3AL@MteNBdgO7aEtDAU55z5hPiECECQG3JbyEmYCzAYcd@cgkgcx/mUgPVHjhW5/x3HBuHUkL8gaigwIOQ4W2XIS/n/Q85IyV1v1juB0wfj2NK7QO8Xo2sJrAURAgVSlOU@Yu1GxNeFA5Lj7yojsFJd3cb665kkp05Mb4jVC7IEjgJuH2oVhVSc3KFa22dd4HIHUNPG1PS51Ao9/AiDPNa9lIhy0haXMxDLkEfGTIUzd8TAOl2Q8A3gldGXT5ewXfvMdB0bK1nehaiBFNWwDa5Fvqx6AY22tva1R6vrd1nkUGM3nNW5up2P9Xrldj3oXbZjOQOHrQMAoqYsc8Tet3GGE6QcXx9DjzLfUgVtDRwQ9Rdx0DCiOdNiLpI3dYRUCF5@DaMAW17oGcCKMh/tf7ULbIhayGYh/6EtS1dUyLlYrpcRHbtsBhCsAliIN9iSXxnj4YW7gE6eE8yb@DR5SB2Tz2TpwEJCroIe/paCzndy7gL9PPTqhaZlZd8lmQAn7@bl6oXSL3ArvNtACePXnNE1rIqFSG80@Kx9kXC1lAW6FU0VSP2R4@vK5zKQaHzEkEOWTCZ4SnItqUgSPgXyYlqDKT3jTEEqNYt5umt0l8Y9NYyugr44uLHQsLR6Qs8VVdOCy6YHFJO/wzqIQl4v/yCdRsJOuYvS5pmGQf54ODFiRnfoMKEFIsZ8yQQYIIYgK0tQ88AAolwSBQtWhGK@MwGxrmdY5sj092nO3rJRdpGJeMtItQLfHaA3swgOTQMYcj7hMBtkcF59NkbZAw7/HCg5xQoivsyr1DV6yvostqeO44Jc6TGV5hS0qOpHgYfieOOe7E8hAh5ql8Z3Lxznnx082m0fbh0/risTz1UsswM0ome0RyDMWtAdVlyYN5wh3AXcMW1nZEKJwijfnlrPHcfnzAMuHNzvimPAMI4nj9pP9refbz3/dpA5GtHN0cTSMY/VxDWAKI4jgrk1mq7TcYC3sCcrYwLm4mD74EkYy2cvnuxvtR/tHh4cz0XzemKZujpVxqeDVQX6DEGYKmd51R9YvcUVHRJTF2YRAmKDMleNgWzKJAmeErrxRFEqk9EDWWQcHiUJZ4F1nOd2maZmK5VeRy@XjWKvm8@X@nq/18trarnQLxe0QhYepWLFYO8IXJKMKc3cgInPiuAEEqYBmaeXKudDDgdE0S5wLBdL8xX53pK5bqFglPIVvdKtVCq6VurldK1cMoxiqZ/PZo2imu13ymo5d2vm5rKBrNXMNqIZIOh1OFlAnkD8UvBa6A4888DrnbOepmnFbqFfyWm9Qjbf61SyhXKvo5b0TsXI9vM5VVN7XU2thmFxRhWoxBAaDLlKG1jT0EtSwVOMhYPpfBPTKmO4DB0QnEQOScw4XEZGwSHwyKPHJFhExqnZwL2A7uESMk7RBO5FdB/hAvKMkyVr5BgAlgkQ15FltxM6VtAxWkFeWFsFUhnQz2X@qwMFMV@q2SuM/BzXoOfKd6mq5H7m9/sLzho5n0o4lFkz5xw58xXoxbXfoLA3vJYCR/HlKT6@cr00vhteS4Gj@Ao8PlzxXh7dNZ9loFFkRYoMV8iXxnXNYwlgFFOJYppfVZ/5lclv1ZJ6kNZS75WBorgrFDdfLW@/5qsV7WCxHLGZd5Bj4MSeOMA/PzFx3r6/0GNikQTeignhNMLiRNLMR5stkzDpbPn6jjAfEScGpn3qkOAcmdpZWS1gLFEUo1PrZsg@iBr0WAC9kambPnz8GnX69FgCgIPu9Zk58qBpz2Doh6FWV57TCydAl@VgcSp3IfmO0Z@AFKR0TBvNd4BJlTJB9jsdcxUo1ARuPgjfS8Cq7PkEJFFNzstqKPbi0gnQbD4Pe7x/QIAdnYS4xfl/tlD5/sT1IVTw/s/f6UEj3GyioX5BsmBkaNvGOeFHf2WLBUHRQo/lrTsb9aliyHRXlF0dl1x1KzIsj5paX5KGujtCkStobkBQfAAm3IJrPOd8LiZ8L0@kyqiSF9cZmG2OWHcJNMFeWxLhiZGQbTl6j6qBi8KmQYFcbGzeDMaUC4VzDA@MPKsSWrJywWZbBfzhxJ/wJ@4OuKsZzTHet3XRADJb0DuqASyy3jGNWxrd1U8nPUcCTo@KjBkrLoGdlZ4m66S@pZ9yYxuNy4vPC@iagwHwE8F7Fdj5EGQbEkqVc3rdhReePfHGUgcay4eOQzbqCqNbUnAt/lwFYgb75yLD6lozLXrco9Ej5CJ0AZaOKhq3NElzlWZeq2ZL71ygqD78eCzDBInBAZpT76bT2RwOe9Ha7/xWpNXhcayk8JXK8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyR7olab0540qKHk4dz0xLQGneRupaugeo5QfNYZxB89HjNnTHkakLYpc7M92C7LPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVdxzI97NrWKgp6fQFuliZuZ6PH3JS0uaxie8QzeUMpMi2nC07Xx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoOc2RnVaV1nXO8V7IWQ@fM4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs7t0ROl178JU3A5Ej@X1eLo0X37XWuq@2AfCKY55Ae2eeO2ZluOxI3reVi0DF4Lx53KMnq9BU7clWg@aNy8PFmRqzORglnVFu@rWwLGK5YGiw2Nl40/cPo4Jwfu@1C@iXqp6N/UK@SPHVoP3SrJ/qrind7UdLU24uGg/Z7xlBF5GwoJFydUFBEkCd@IsL9xetkwhZYXLy6sawO0Oz/WL8P0bjCyrajccWcYXxG8D@4cBKmUw@C7nwX@T1PK3p9a7H3m6EW3prkLMNe6pZcBARs8bTcq0rPqRIdRs9v7Eqm9NjImxlFYddF4buL/9Fink/pnKBsVIBLOdOCOEc50R1NtAfrxXrnEMR9utBEa3TOjkd3I6S@ndGHj0MYrch2A4RMPNgAN7Ml5o3AUpzn5@e80Nx2HPdnoLmUSfj6VI5bv5qQVG3jPovlW44sIgrm3Vc9lsNuBv5uavFyy3CV25KOxrkz8XEiaXWcozWJwNceeMy9OYTaVC05unnoSTmvejTtqqGQECrlQU27QN/wKfq5pkGbXtOI71MU0IRLdnIv8GXCku/NzVlDd4o2A3GJvNfXg4c9Lpr5r14ANSIJ1C7aHgfRs2zE@93quZJVyyhl46uGa9fR5obiL3rlRgmKfJJb51wlrNeAYzKqpclku39kjOzjodw9L5a1rM3xZfRc7dGl/EsgR8Mq1t4XoYXwGbrajGr9Gt8QVUltkDIWdojAyy3iId6L3XEy98rQSaOngv8ZZpvXFVuLEJhMLG58Jq2xwr5Ts2iGW@7g4MlGssXBUPXFcR53BWfWnl7o/0gcHPVd1GPWdTHbh1mEuDM@PySY8q33XWhWB868ftqACd6dS48ML30gifXnShPSeju6fqrvX7Lm1Uuqujy8rSxYQ7eEV76AztoTHkO4Ei26ruARjp8xNxtxUC8j8YdhnRp/ldSvM1azmWdZ@aRfrIqaXj9JfmaRfPafUg6EfFe6F3wCN43TkFCGM9VRAN@qv6zdCYwJDlOb4zNiSyrQK1cLKIP1dR0XBx5zedhbp1hgBqJHz/pvHfKZsOdMcfj@nVHlsTjx4UVKLjdcuaco@SuQ9WmD7fdsTx1hg4ne7QvCtLHUP3bfNUCWeEuPVWyXY8Vwsmkx6hs2yZUHnuhYzYUJ/3P8LX/qomDSaX@LAVGZa3cZXtTFz3AmvCdxzmWc75jD4s7p@IpnH56gMaVuUgWBlc4k3cAO6sC3eQ3bIEEiwkrkQwYsKR4ZaMLDAs6soZpYXtnXO9I5fjj1V80bXyU6bm1m8/Zko02PZAk4Pm3MwtuC/gz8Ji9NLByh5OBt5Ncscn7HvAYuFjaUtvDfBM87WG5o0KI5BuB69V9a1ZCm7fhncbWm5i3Lq6Urh1eYXgVEvSHRNebXhBG05WTptZ5tjjTyb1taUMw80l5JtQF8vF5qB9ekafr4Wg6S5Ob@S4eIgIWAqp6xpeF6fSkSJz/olTH9sZAGWWLDYDDmGXFuHmqvXS5o9GPOnLZ8ZAx@2VT0zcaWktwQqI9fri9V2Rfmuie@a3Jo5vLI3v@gL2XdE91Qdm9/FCzYeRhTUa7MHjrwW0R6eblX8@ND06vxEabplzQiTjaIt41gZ@f5m0dm26PjoYffu0yhyjFOz9ZtI@C/eIRwZcMEB/fWlay2binTHJjRdkum0S3vRpZjZ4L8Wq5ZsAbkv@fDIaT7zgtTx12qczP0U9OiV379wEsii9AWrMhrrlL5/GnpuZBZ4rGCRnxlVc@Fem5QzYV@UsAxYNBm1kypcg3DYM14e6Dz3CXoLAlPY9F0px0kNyecHeAE4YOSaZtunfPsHj@zrISOEbC8MHGzyFqDzBp/zwY2OQjpfXyJNbORgY2y@6Fh6K/1hJgJNdwMIjOrSOxujc/DzeB8kYO0GE4ehiG@fz8tqtiz5VHFIde@JLuMv/tjGleOuYUmXTcnEONVjqW7tPX4jzGELbX@/iQw0QBCeedTEzrdx4cA3xTBuYtdW0eBE6lCYeGaTS4Dlt1LwjzNYYT08RyX/kLJN4Di9g9Lm3yAQDyGT0yOjiyuOdaT9zngLrBkPZGIju6LmBWwau0ZLlATHYE6erW1A/vTuTOaJol4wVM@FaHxsdaF9rZlrOiy2L@JHu6yt4J5o4JAkwMt2JK6bVMdzXNCM4Z14l1C5m6LExJTFkNcLwXij53S5nuHFabqGPXF/b8caOY/MnEeEsvNSntxMbGB7ocf8Vdxn3Ly@MfkuFtMXSHpzx7SZGjx/cW1Vc1@g4Fn9iEVaQA9vkmwt01zQ85YlpT6bkxiTg3ZaLOXwbb1Yu4TSHN4TOdm6CjB3t7sXNanyrsHdNkgKW@Ez3aMl/uUyzsJP4/ruKhrrbdXDtLDB85MrZ3JGwO@h4tFWab03oQKNMgaDp3UmoV@COrFqjzogeK2WSuZZ@bnTwyF2Hzo/6@nQZE7l4dCxwvHZ4KyRp2PGLLHUIUo9490B2XWRbrHFzTA8i6OdL0SRM7plpdN/q4h20NOpFNJes6CTRLu1Ii5vggM2xDMkf4h5LxfdXEYxn5umkd4@1rnABZTIycM16ceVmJVI53pAwwlm@Sh8RXNcItm7jLkHo@qEZqa60tRJlMXr4H2x/psDA3C7m8QT/ZCoNgJzdvS8AMj9x7eB1H7Q7dDy/b04PxqjGyXFX0RcsVgGCwIt3BzStryoEtKc9sfh8x2BuR9eoR/IdcIN9B0wWkXDfkAz7TCIVR9NwudLVQz0yq9owOCVCCm0i1QdeJji/BG6mG5yR9uRQO1OcznpR1w1PHbA4qmeY4CwDFF9mBJdK6em0KMZ4INwBMrABLIQi9TKoeoJrrvEYsGk@wZp91myyxOW0mq2qV6zOhKrATk54rHiRIoTd6Zh0wzznwZsJ/aSeSEpSMpFs2VWWTUbghgXiyVJwfQG2b9KL53dWBVxvlENKn6IS17hqDSAbqLZmqNs9y2AvbFqWA57S5QoiuPaRY9xu@ss/7gXafEhr1cj0dAsqBBVyOSNj6Jxv8nSD1IHb0lEbEMYBkqbFdVNIO1sMxBy/O@RKfJxz9mLvuByoBgm0f4HlkE8WRbngjYsrVnjM0eeNx3MTHVkLEo5ChYUC/nkysmHA6vlDT2ZHJp1gnLizMwmBTjTbd3Faupdh@6xn4M4@OphKqzCW45zSYRXMyS//mCtEoeOpwbHBMHlShDSXIp5CVUkLSbfrTCDXYSRvDdcJQFJYySBbTnDNk/RwkbuIhzZJUwtgpBTqKaFkuLKSna0jJu2yJGr4Qr0CNbOfSmw9//TzZvak/p6NFOM/f0cRL4OKEz6RKkVPyLAQpHaFiDXvXQDvmW@SCYmpwBOMzu6aAYd8ztsDtZNxJMPjuyGOOc446DWka4pUK0XYGKgsSKGZ2jlUWDIiNVWEsMY5KSyhQ2I20gBSk@ZBBwOrSFHzXldPpCZ8GU468lkBEkSlLzqYuGIrOs2KyjcwSGLK3rEhIhnwXGohCzZekRbqexnVt8N937n5/fjKI6MzoT2pZ5qsFepUnES7vtEgE9B0B/UuNV@2plpWak1LuyfARQaV2mpNP8lqX0KtOy6EeqBgz9t99ugyITey7955@gUThKtkjZ8fADKRuDzcP9w9Ot46fnEErXAVkp89fooopDWIRXQwcOhYpNEK6gXZuY@gP5EN9UukWEJnG6gzURRj80e4CDSoa0ESEtw4R5oWQt8RfFl4z5jzvwkQ0LS@yUKM2odhANsQkA1rDQs/GaNeLhaEDXQLEZaZSOOxA0UVg6c0ltBSqiqB1aGyJKise1YVW13YTe52nxq7M5bbq21zKQjWWJReM/LnRVxaBVf/IOUew0D5315uHsvt5SaYW8oNoJFrGGZva//Ji@e7i8EAx@hNVLdeKQRnFzlxxp7GWcJQmRKpDAgC4jJmXWACBeDWYDDjKh0N/9yAYgXEsTvigQlDKf9CbIaYUDN11Cp6UuN1kUpRDpAHqWGxrh2tBH5tLovhGD0X3SUvYkQE9oQo6jDjshDEHCftmDJeYTEw1qC6wq53SEQ8oNdJb579yYQ9DouGY/TE431uxVAVjToeg//cqBSatBM2ZcFwpp4wiWlwW4Y9gAKHsGKNj1EswStCSPC8C1F@Uash5Kn3WqeVAzoyEBxJhFHa0seoQi2Afub4RpW9mTik9iAkJhF/QQo1da6ElJqWq9YkdQogqgF3Go5bFN/@3lEduTPOmhF9n8e5iY0DFQBxfaDBwWTfRb25/MQoV8zHq9wJdMCFQyVJ316g8yniEjx2ZnomyI7UCH3kcSyglFiaoOCoU5YUXrAtywOepAfDN3AoPg61wJzIdI6NH2aTbCbEASfliGXMMCGGsF79pk4wGErPUZp4xQMnCI5i9ubiTG6sSRLU3MC0QwWyVdQoS4JnlfnuBLepNZI3goRZqJJJGvojaw5wiXbElqF8@N0/4BoRWz6YfxCYp9ltsP12YOuD@XdCH1UF2z@LbBrYfshtLxVssptq4Gb5jE70rzz5B8j5ULhRMCQMoSpdKlDU5Njcn@8fMq@LGlqxQUf6dK6tkMwg4oFYCEg4Asw4o4ZGcJ7CrB1n8aSanwOeAHIBkiCPg2wNpWe4JynUCFZVFMw4LijItF/QmPI1fFIQ9maCijGBE1OKhWJeVSCT0lkYIeksGeDxJR6hKFaBMMbOzHH9VafLNjY2mOB1dcuoF2scQZSE/jInvIoymgDYGJcWmgzCQJBZCPBrBMFSCT2tihgUR7OkmkTC1nM4vgFLmCIDgIjobIdaDoDndIKqAmS2jalPbNNFKAUB1badOY24YUQSRMTjRvWN1/vk7EgSzoLN9VJ5vhmELxDsCMGqwjKMbb5kLb9lnwRqPBlg30@X4K8N5n@yRLcnxyzU4nJTqWTqukpILA17eGQ7OJm4B7llKU3RcopaFOcwVAiigvxif38HUUIPB4rRNczXztjb2tnd/@zg8OiGciGCTF4HS7JkYyPdkuRM8yQyJKN8L1bq9p5y9HR7L6zK@VzNpvMQYrY/83o2l6V2PacrUv@Cn/66mTZ53EhIzd43Ytr8JO3RPuebsc98lTnAHX745EaqKfHyqnmy0WjZ8RvJv1umMDYuryNyganlkbrY5PVsYhYj5fDHqBzek8OjzSqea8YDb75zOjslHTjMeXDwMBagADFZCaFWEU/IwAGfpJmp89C4dnqPSB@fyCE1nlGO5iCPQz322LVm2ucCtWtD3RtaZicGA3gPVRFypSmhVpBI3YrsjS3TT4kxmgKpIxsERCwVaLOfVqcyrUKmSGksxZVht2lyC@MTY9AJIL7k4cQbskNnzGbzT4@M0PQcuBH2aMKXqAz22WQEcH16PTeQxBrAn0gQGCoqGWWVS9XQswJFbtM0KsuD9Jqozi0ouDzqFVJTUR4a0545AAKeEjPQ0z9Rga2KjppjoUm5m50EGsdr@FM89DNfpR@lz286i1xv6rJp94xpChXUVE@AP0X35PkXZ0lRuIEDpFRwJ1RDdk27YNgRdT/oETPNfNc6WyVSYX9N/WOlgkp@8NQ8NAukeOS7T8AI41OqP9LHLDUhtZcekxlZU62UnfF8V2RSg2vOsFk6TVI1vMgDuGYE7ZOJEIelUEt0SqlD66CrZ/fw9dYcs6YqyydgpkRElsAZtR0YynEuSoyBlARBqhRtHduWVTFHHHtljnkQBv1jpIeLoe7HJd6krZEmeR2sCyo1azyY018064G8ViuVatAai6SmwgAtblJ5WYFol5CQkEuF@g0OQUOtoTZzVHuPc@BAFh5@07BtAyoIcGakwxisTwDJXDETfr4iM9N@TSnEeRYfB6eqIaOLWrF3k5cWLpQmlBpNztSuYEx91cJBtR8MqxfK/6jISu0ylbDqFwowOmIjlRjW1XRuPZ1O2OuphI1D/YMHOKdzlQBOoi2DiDQFIClhiTXAZ@A86gm7ltA3UoleXVunEGAFIe0SArz3FPkyoV8piQcwUmfAxeWdN5XwSLFiVpbVK8gf9pCEkgGcuUQ9dPTtCkw@YabTmAc50cYMvFdaR2mi2a0jhaaPagE3qgxGQXe7RlWjlrjx5Q5egYFz0NBA2DUk7MFm9nYIPNOJnVvmt4L34Al/E88LMdqiaHjz7L@w6HN/whLQuyTpvOJqLLlmS6jAaQoqEa0ZXRSBmPz613G1yIRUYrOYO0snC9kaPNRaiRXYJ4mWlo@z@EMQ15V1wRUuW4/KZ8zoa8U3ktTU@/Kbk8PTw8MvxVYqGd85eCmoeQAtsQrd971KTFtxsY@74vF1JRZX1tUHJUV59eoVsLtwNRtyYx5KPhGbUvKkmSqBpVEqrWeK5fXMw2SbsiKmNE08YqapsJY59no9uJ0hfUEmFecX29zEtMAAfxa4jaZ97jbLDAcJXMOwodddcFW9EGetkq6vp/PaQ7sma1ntl79Yu8pcHrY3fvndkWKs4esAXz@4eormI7XwydraJ9vb@XwGKo@bD786/PbW1lb@UaZw2Cxs5qXs2sZf/cXamqZtaMraieepJ8nm6ZeCls0L8i9/njw8/Fbb87D98MoxFYz4LMOtskKBnbK3cJ32Gf7J/LY3Z9bR3Om/xQESmOU6EZtkspBLHr1MYnHfxlVVjV/Qr03VsMbUxmbpv/zo4E3cjzc05QsX3n78TbxYjnMjGMCWC21n8UZ8A8GKV/ELpV6vg7H0X/4dhG98BvGgz8UGPBqFMK7iRbwh1SnIu3ijCAZV0yDd/@c734nFG1NEhMb@HtMa2jrHFbX8QH3Apvxirbhazh88BOfwCr2iiymqqrXC9pxrbmzayHkIhYd2Zc6cW9TuIWbEWYANZPgYOPzYUHHt4atHbKMBQy1e1erDCNUUVioLjgPduQa2J5H7c1mCS26H9hpapaAI8XI90@bJR7ganzNcK3D0ZEHZI/tHwu3i9df/11//@K9/RL8f0/2fYvFwG4HUPGucNMKLCQ2kTyywPbXZU37ZNvzhDq3ogg5gstmsLPF4o4EP@gc2MtH7mlvg04gsBDELcgtcQDMo3Vj8PbQJYh87ayxcrKGwyExF4Lkmw9O5ks3KhiiwCdca/OgPV2TF5xq5BM4EcvNaY43brlupbyzejDdPTqrUme5/seVxx89icQlIQzr9HHjGAJnvc72AW5bbgS1C6ngs/g96NWIsfgnXSVq6umrKL9O1WvAHVqoW2fDiJsjTyZUkbbxspNNNyluzEWRyQzppyKzN80uPlxsQb3qjuVF3duiW21hHUjLvJIvOw5OXjebGYhxBNA8fprEzP4R4GokTBkw81OzVxlXjqrlxdbWxAf8Nel4Fb3C92rjxp9fsqq0Aiq6rE2z0VlNptJRW0KAnYJeVBrrISgsMDXi3AbDZjMUvEV9Y84R0cdWlplosnEiM@sR6Ff26HmNVdV3LKYXpJ8VdLRbXBEFZR693ODIBf1GJxZFLr3BmvUIOrz58/X/g3frw9b8BK2QNv3lGvp03@HvyFn9vfPwdd/H3/A3@jt/i77mPv0MPf087@IvF64wBc5TYzFrZs6x6qp6CwWRZ4E2H2aHaw8Ega7DsRfaCZUeO2gOTAb8smMxsn2UHLGtnbVUFTzD4LOujqQ@vAfz6EIsLPzObxcizZwxSsXCIIRW29H7XZmIr1mTCKwO4GllNytmkXEwmzZNCcfxGyCTbrWbypBZXvFZL4fwe0/I10l18dcXa7d1nj9ptBXtA66lzMPsfHIzmrbf@RwfO0wNn5MD/4ODgKbR3@mFaeghXvZHeCF6b8UZts1WVEI3lAKHjysZmq5GT0FxMA3Jq6Jb@yGsWI7wba60YCMNffHFe@@IL/J@f1c5rZIisYGjXIoAAjBvAkTtABF/UamRAM1xnFCvZ0Hj@RSsycYPyxTk4fcGAPY/@yoLtH@Bv/v/r//QFSzVPROgHl1cbKbpE/Ini5dXlVfBsiKlUYEltwA8dwI5BLq8aaCSgSzA1U@KJeHXF3eCZEjd4hA1MY6NBgWeAQCviUZqULn@k/mHfmDa/Wkngj0BuTQWLbq3WNJsVax1wiWbe9Xe0fiPWaGdLooNrbiCrqSJBFPK1mrrOzVpeq9XygaVUrtXKgTmRSlVuXo3splosVrV8XhRrtWwAC2JZLTRCFIand2vYvWvxsYi55Z0@lcXJP/pgQVKoCg8epIJPXGyOxyCmq5Xsu3eRU7vdM912G91z794JbQF3wdQrBbBny@/eAeFJiiDAP3P4@mtKUtknWoNSqIBkruVL4M1URZulOdQ93ffd1FtznBFwm5oniKRkOJt13FbyVz/87ndbyTruiyDXvIoRYCqssLFRzDcaxTyYi2UouZDgG21Sg3RFFa8SisDLCwJ4Mh54qeWSSK5XSfRn8Q222YCO6uHFLq/i1IAsXxBTnQtDvASX0E2tVLgjyxdT5XQl@NXXRNZYZ8Gv2Wzm0vn10vrDk5OTa/w@EtPapV5Xr@qXehVnh65q3UCLPZ4c0R88yFWgFsvZWivWbj/aOt5q4wfwcO0bRj6GjkSWY7iuOXaTTZrKK1ROmliik1YyWa09pAZXywUWT9YCOCkJFJ6VK1TwuOfFzD4eIZtSrNfu9fiYqaUcDKmxMe1BKmVZD5dxXeb0@2vgCC3GOrji7hmWFar9P3dcq3du9oy1WPzwydbO7nFG24DRWdvb2sloRy@24ypaCzM7eefQ/nx369HBCwhw@GR362j30/3Pd18cgrsXe/1WNwzdmBjGeXsyOX@DmuGNtjEG19nVNrqmp79@rY/pYjVOkM/PP/z0@x9@@j99@NkPP/zs@x9@9uNfff3j78P9x3D/kL9/@G8rBXz@6ut/9kcf/vBn4Pif4P6PcP/iV1///nf4TfY/h/sv59z@PLjn4PjNqvHGOl6ACGWtnF6HEW@9UgFkINeNGKT127/6@kc//9XXv/MTuP9FcP/k5v27v1h@//h7q28M96M/uh3mh/8O7j/hcYWwP/xD7obvG/B/yOF@5ycffu/f8/9fBT80/uzD7/05PgLLP/3JX/3lh@/@B00r/9W//vD9H3743o8@fO@7H773gw/f@8fah9//12p2/vFHH378p//1z/7kv/7Z/0L/P6bnn9zn/@En//Rv/s@/@b//5s@C@xdw/3sw/eJv/gOg8d/96U/x/6M//bv/@FP8/@//8u/@9H/9u9/@V2T4A274f//Fv@XPv/3u9//2e//8b7/79Yrn9299fn0P96//O7jcP5/3iec@5fpYl69/o/z8t9TGLBXAAVLRzzRgarcvDFZjsSzLBg/ohD/@Jx9@/7cAt38PIMH2P4MN/twCXj8gy5dfLvilaY5DSn/5JQiHXwZC4pfzQD9g7J0CDHj24TsA@JJ8@cUiKEj0f0MoAGMBVAi2kDiB4P5J7vyrr//5z9E9ComuvzUfXzZ0nYNNIPC7sIg/wM4cFWMe9gdIDj789Dsffv6PP/z0Dz789LdxLJDylcxWBsbw22dQAbBwDzgELN4HDgBVFBBBkl@LaWBY28AZv5iafvUKGmENTCBfrccKObDF1AaZVTRDQJD71ymSaRonSeCexvIVsIEBnKZkAK80eG2n8XPM6di0Dn4Eit9xZmhslHG2DqcQ6hAvBuJhMu0yyCxsuk2xQMh6@jlrr9enPGAaHRoUA8MModNzQdWEdLn@CBKsTx8xjAsjT8dewftVvVGuTxsY3XvKAsSR3oYkAQo/E52eNt6DvU5xAnxs@ug9ZKVcT6cbZXCpU1EptUyb0lQLVDgqe5pRudGdMdzDuPmQsU8EtSzwOQ6oShZA4zM9g96kKcBN8G@l14Pi0D800r2O4aGdplQ/3I37b6IzhQ8AIF5Jwq1vcEsS5uYheE95VGlKFl5pHgPUXJpPkbLIgRiUdCxN7ZsmC6QPefiYa4MPzhgdFieRSIBpoyHkhPYBiIrMPa16vu7iwhzxi1UmFCsCOuMuIr4/MnFIEuX6o3V4qvDfXaM9wVSS2noskcQJiiQLU5LSOSfvxHkhwhKSbZ0KkCZA9gn44P3wIZihhug9c4vFZ@G4kEFrsEwt5pkYS9E3h0SaBTGQCWKxp95g25kCf58RhIxaxLUVkc@RxL7tVKv192q@FIM32Sf4taPguzvQWPjNZ3ljAyu9cSnRdA0agTEsxhqNYBGZqbHG0e4xgB8fMFXLygykgct8ScsX8gUtVywWSpqaL1byxUI5B6SsmC1omlrJ5yvlSumKyvIQqEGmut4pbDT@0Y3rf/hHy67lrnjFGl@yqUxz0VexhlXnGxkTuJgstLJCjaaNqOYSzWwGf1ouB0/IY0YtlE7W1qxLCYvcot1zl7hcD9mMXUo49/0NuFjsGzH2DXCCC9LA5TQWbIDYP6gFi934wUK@4C2oBcAdMdYC3OGxQSNeXl7O3bH42ldf@azRAL5e2t@LxQHnhyxc3ZXMnjyU6TODvYlrkO@AsUf7n@8f7R88kx/tHwGv/W2m5bJyLH51ddWP1iTIarCDg4MYEhuQnHIqhr/qsslkQr4dsF9N9dh4/qqNY5omaTkpp0pqDv93GDT83x9eg7@GTwiV02L8YJKF50/COahK7P3791PaOlDdt/1gD4GWL6M7iyHWPwCK/kDlxkJxZsyicSM4lt6I0VJpEzDuJIbfsGqexDaUyPMYNQQ8g6YDXLfZE9wx7Dvs2OE7U7eN7gqInSH/GvuO64Ag9ZvDbOv2Kfd6ZPKjypHXYx11lXoj0x@ugHgxHuFJLcP97xbD7qgDGcRFEw6wDQ/XcpxlACX24nBFKZ9GmkVwVwKpFgHw5/ufPj6eex/vbu08jhXZ9sGzR9dehQCowJ7s7h1H1hL3DYMWoii@vfvkyXVr8AICWiPJeY0VSpkMjEPwwHeGLnrLiZchiCqvZlB0Xwe5vMnyJzVgB8q1TRVnSgoJpa4ePkGR3nIOXaC0LRTQ30sbn9cbeqIPtLq@LTXK79P5UjlnXTZ2h/iJVrfmGlN/YKzZE/aieYL6QqDG8BSeHHuKGyUrKj/1Y3qxxyCQj/CbUPj9Nz@G55x7@N1nnHDp4AeYJ2O20hFe6IRG1xwMYfQ4d0KAWEfXGdwfe0H4eVkcqu5WB5@nQW43fKwl4Lg6b/ZZNiYTddAq5UK5ktPKmXKlnC@oxUIho2oZtVQuVYCSZ9WyWiwXKmqmnK/k8jDUgG@hUorFgQSbfUWBYVQVBHhXIVq7i58x2MDvQTjysBGL82ku9jali9DGkX3CBAPCCPhBLc@nveDrZl3Q8nhQI6cyiFFnXRbf29vJ7u0JwjZacCZ@JysIPbQUytlsaVsQDPLZgeFQEwSHhwEvAPO5JZvd3hGECY8AlaIIwhAtu0Xk7wXBRMvO1t4epvMaLRqGB7BT7sMtVmgpAZiNllyOBARBeBNFB3BbPKE85XQXLZgm@uxxnx3wE4RPw/xksxDDcw7HY3gclnVrSxD2uWVrC30@o4IXeFa/iZYtugTBBQsgoSAMwDBwDcMWhA4YERUFoQum7oUObvjJCFSUYfu6IFzwCsIqEoQpQevdUwEY2cAdk3n8@LE@9HvGgF8XLn93IWvgY04nu3udTz/tDAYd92Jr99Pn6PPZZ4/11xcTtzPoBME6bbgcCAM@p6OL6xfkcb/d1q2lPt8EH/uaT/uibWDe2vobyFNwDTCRUfsz8PkMfKZLLh4bXCMA7eC1PYL3tt4hn/AiH3pPOx2hhojqX4wNnOHDPkMfhs@M9K7r1NA@ra8lU8nMRbOYPamRMxulxMts7Qp9@yn6KCFSR/HyojmtZ09AuClpwWGSlNCaagVTyKyNNoHgVdf0TVXLp6dV1Hjr9JMsKambKfXB@tvUM3FTy@WrQmtzUxKa6smmpparxdLL9YkgiFV8buZK1bepbDLLGD7EZulks1SYC1EqpXVFq5ZKYu0KasKHIaoz8Y12O5U6N/RTUcS8In8A@adisgsqolnrp6aZaZ1nil2ItWldrfGj2ix7I64e6gqZ4Je/eIwDiG66ma0i8U4JaqUsQPqKkhJFpEZIP@D96otw1Sd6zRkWjPySWVXinw1Uy0VRxmMJbaffpk8nsVfzkMhux77AM0R0fjjc6keCiVeNHSN3jgOAzlAfUQe/VEpHtkE45PptGJ/7UEuVWKwRMKiH/KMttcD66eMdGXjWwIZaR@Q9/EC148r4YVV/wYdrxAidjmG0kh8buIGvG7rt8JO98u4UxA88vVC7lL6QruZDHAEfztPAww01OmmOx4RR/YrZY3q9ASa9x1KUPtPFcypnu9Got@sjYzT2L0Aq4mvHUKow@LPJiG0zDotnjsITF@36NlRAtmajCjIDrYlpfBpr9FDBynZ9@3JSRfbyqmbU6fPbQhzPaW3a9Ynt6X3j0HDxiND@AQzbBp7F6Q5ftXYRcAcq@/JKarjMnhVi3@N1FB34oAxdYoYCj3Y9e1Wbz3VKlxodsTaoNxH0HT42JEE4kaTmuxMQtmqxBvS@2kVcr3uTDv9GXbYDclaxNgU3tZSvDVmn3nk5rbn1MYgHrGZBLc5JPUyvEfw7CwbSttyuT2e1kas3NZB7splQEtJw/1dGy1YymgojKYywEBLuEtjzcKtwg7@KclLKSgmMCZnsNCurGdVQMyBmvjJ7r8SM7@za0CLZahUbBhqVrPDWmZjW1q1Uz2H6hkRtDF28RhnXM0M2NuGRgnDPDd2iAKIosZT0ZrOYLmRFsfYGcu0mUj15W9zM13qpbdYWwQF4A7g1VszX@vXUS3GxjsVaak2se8Ybqk8kFVQZ4zVojkAW9CajZpatFdXMpdSWrizd8xNqSas2J4mmpEJps@8GG8JXDeEEmuaKxeA3v2gDrEcN3EKywJmVGbsxcxsj82kZ0IpqRasFILFxQKRSQgq/X8y3m6aSyZKWTIrJGs46rIF7QOSIIiWBPCYfqJsCsDtCVahoIGPOEbcbWeCCVRHEv6tYz/TGDESs@GXs6vJqY34HzTfZxYWelkLrA8YG6USMKbSKLrfjbI1MktygqaGt@tbg@VYtgN7aicWrtF1streHtYLzuZKy9rFL9@mNxkv@buFuFUg1Rip3muwkkBO1HJS5N2eH8nmXMV6rfBOHspFuKK2YIFDf5ut/5YLIc8rex0l7Pdu57AdEqfoURU2W0qu8zzZPxPfPTOuynJMaJEumWPx9GmoEd741lPdxGBauqKKD/WWXl@PLS5Csr/DMuZYrxOK2E249AwnVBzII40mhIOBEjMHGR5WXpZfll09fHLw42GMPs9VytTwvZ7QeZjJqUk1usIfAxprPd0GGececgvre/ow23cVr8eo4mcsncwvB6vFpPR@u8KbURkNSNzS2CbjKqkCh@mpRyr5rcMRrkEdRA58Pv/WT/HSjDHYNWMUq1GkhrTUa6romxscfvv43eIzrcvfzrScsiQX8@7/4uVb6@7/4l7SqmLyq8UKX4gCJRrVYip/EeRbyJSaCha9tq/GGErirJVWMexK3QfYKce9doFUjpWXL4LdzwG1CEWotXonH4uWnr94xtgHCZKM3GJgamRRlQUBLVEHogj97j5NX76W1V0BPPC@h4HbHCgKHMy7rjUZjnXZBJhtpPH6oFWiiv3lVO@EzIiiHrNv0M7x1/BkvI4d1zwN7aAPr@obBCg2VgeCiKB9@6/c1rfj3f/G7LfFd@137W0BhK5VKUdXiv755xQNdQBrkxbD5VtgqHuSVynxPPxLu1x7/sHh4npE@Kg0cMml38ejLpJZpn0IA5AnAjJ8rBSaiyu55eDIWDNlv8TRPYO7onlHMhzbvwsN96DhXiIcZvaqiDEx/OOnQ6cVj92LfP6CzHQrgiwmSP5k7ltNRRjrOONA3qjwQogACVZpPbAXGSTyaQd/wRL4V1VS0Sd0SFK3XBrA2FislVmMMUh7jUevWtN8X6Iy2YfWOjLFOanXAPzzIut9DMFS6RCfAw8PHCzxVdPKYatxgyR2@AV@iI@QOsTJeMjx0SFXLSL2FgUdCBDwEHRxlor31gow2/CyzEO6rB4i@g3pXQ3j6cvMsQPQh51kILCNqYAk4h/p8iViayp8OM4GzydyB8jGzBonOHCghyo3LzIzuDkihmI0qmSCtFDSrjPolm2r1JMN5zbpK9U1n3U22UWfAwKNGFyoJVihp2eybLrBranlO1wsxaxRyvhzpepATAOQNgme7UZsWnlRwOq9J@1CgdgLxTw79guP@qLILjThBYweaZdl5x/QJAIY2AsCQygDPAPEqyiygamcywMMV2Bdkxx0opudNjEKpnKcM6XhiOwQF9nYBVFMCddcKZQ4PSEelqPhDZhlnhkUqCIJso14lnXdKwjPcRoOqFJFJL4qEOlCVCyWFWkhVMtzt0e7ek63j3UcZJqkFBMcTbl0ngk3NVS73TpN/35p4wwCNMAjvvnKnmOdInvIyyYdKUgyy/nC@2tPzGQ4jwK9S4fTgOJWsUzDXGOEnwHjEbKz3kFZlKIydDE7x4/F5fkrM9DArE9dCvAkrN@z58biAKI1pxREFFz5DD2GwYAFvAzYgPDeAVtIKqIGAurV9wEjUUUKYKyw77g6EVZIaXAmDsGPhNwGTqPJqntomqe/oLHmM@shhSCfStpYkuoBqHob15CdestYFtj3kKdhZaiJeBiUw7T7mIsUr7tjZvgjbLzUJzt8IUCEiMMZidCDnl3@ZBD4jis@zUr54eaa77G0dMJR6nMyJ@q5F5xxTSa6mFoK9lZHnCM691f1aFKDj9C5k1MJn93aGptVLvZ1PYwysptlPpdPdej0nXkKS7hiIkzcGYmigMCfW0K2/4AYW0paTUlotG/Inr9vGOfvy6ZPH0OTPDTrW3nx5sp5QMsDaijUsgl5PIdCjg6eHuusZriiP8b0XiU0p/IpHkIgMrT3ymtkTyn1GwKIp2AuBcg4MPyi9t31xrA@e6SMjldST/EAZJmVCo5gbuszlo5qZTotQRL1pnizUUV1YbFxBvBzUCWroGv1aByr6tHbl1c9SA7Hmw2s4n0QBkqhrGsXuQ6C6B49rtW7iN70fHz99Uk9u6AxjrS/pFcl0J0IOQBRCGDopv@W6@sUC6gBVIazy@ZlQQhi40kmhsViWDUVvJIFlXZmfJw5pspBlOTlD4F5qkgkwzq3fbNKaO8OCi7FRRwc@tH26eyxkIKw7MUR0tHF4uyCixdUd1MM0OLohpaAh8OIIYer1/IMH5MZVndTrWjYrAmrWriA2DzA3FYk9bu3K1eu9VFSR@thcolpBkzVFt71zVM0NLG@2UNp0XBgi6j3gIR94QELqqH76zPQvHniAbfVQTcMDft60vpZfLx@Y29/6snJUfJTqdj5ThYzw2nNsENHc8XwGXP1c5mwR0Fi3y7GLMoFqOru6MtZPHSXfy3bL2bJa6hmlglHO5srdgpGrdIBL7Pbz5U6vUtJLhW5HgcHNpyDyyMSvRgkc/THZ/v2SXcWYlUHk7/dV4NZ7hUq/omVzuXynXOhl8/l@WdVzuWJPK3cqndu5tll@UNwK6S6OHdcp8CermbvYDdoehBb/Pw';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D <> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~ / x    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]:   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./_]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*:  
#cs  :1*23/5x%6E2
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ "`e```.1'.0'.6''i]56pq",'_\['];#/s\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho / ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#p)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#*:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ :#>*****[[[828+*+@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+ rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];=>+8;?1&&195$/=1PLconsloPrs  \puts~-<V=>a$f 16=B->8~+4783l{>Ehar Cr;rextge!nu U[]persngtalle.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment{{p{{}}}}say 235
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ    ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#]#print(47 )#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41491133#41491133) by Potato44.

Oration is Python substitution language. It supports inserting Python code with `literally,`.
Oration code is on line 136 (space after `,` is mandatory):

```py
literally, print 249
```

Python 2 is used as underlying language, so command line is `python2 oration.py polyglot 2`.
Just passing `2` as second argument to `oration.py` is not enough, also need to run `oration.py` in Python 2, otherwise it will try to run generated python code in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

## 251. [PILOT (psPILOT)](https://github.com/FreeTrav/psPILOT), 11600 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWnp3r5zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPAJISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@xz29JHnZ7OAMJwx67hU/QFBlF0TynMok@RsaeO6xmYfNfwPAcdS4xtGKOxf9EASxkgdNd0nmw9@/Ra4Apjn@qQs7FlTK/lRc2yF6bh9q6FUFX2xfHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao597nq6pV@PP8@2Jr6z7193L7CtgWHrTJMrsnbds8i2Xf1GkBJzDb3XNy1DNu0uk9jQsMaGy9CF9R0Xmsw3rHK2nG1vzULKXQxbnnlei7YeXkx3Bx54OmcGGA1oibFp9FjfdUZMt71zSEmtZGfwGG1lER26kEFANPbag9A9g3m2OR4bPveE4houeUPKzDLt0xjHvkPX6U26pj0AOAPqdTzxqUxerAvBGmwc4LCMBhanWuBgkIUjZ2TMt4UHyAu59sZG1@ybXV45xtQ3bA/K68nMhLY7Ny2L9QwLAsxi72aY57CJN@fUsfSh3JVjWLmYChudWsxk3fGYcS8oBmRpL1tmxsh5bbK34G8NPTYdj5hnjsDb7zr9vmGwt8Z4CMHZqBfrOTEGV3d8rWSRLWEAjG1A6XYOvw315mN12n3IWo915uAgH5RnKrFuO1B9LrP1EceG7viCSg/RRCH6jiOje88xPDvps3PHPWUdo6tjsTExzxj09YkFKZp9bA7AA9NjIwfe0Ig2g2xBYB/rAuPGxGJLC4LJhM1rjKFjYvM6iC7Q1mErn7s64IfrBe3omyPADtNPeszQPRMpFgTxDLtHmDGOaJkDpZ1vdHZmQseDqpi4FLdnuIT6FC/DUkCUeoSrqXPX9AEjsBRb7NDQXXbsGobI8dTwuvoYsXQ@SUjMwRR8LIhMiLmxkdw92EsCgvIQsj4GhHRzx9/6LKYzuc4S7RrcdUGoxXafPWKXiRaaOc0EJB67KV1k9ffMU1otA@6p2lEG7lUMYo1BrVhMcca@oktjyKDkQwYVHY1oks40eWzNJcw2rrXBXLfhUD1oDSAC7IsMlaw7cV2k7rNK1U@h0JZjD6A@obDuxOZNXsxCEwD@9bwMM84MxAHeRs451fDxEDAE/gA6R1n4gEMVCkMOdMWgRsN0PceaEByE9Hzsj1ArEBRj3O@zL1hfNy0MAv4YFc@1a3iAnBhmYvew5UembfRkFmaDqI4LffEMktMhUnKA3jCaoy2UKQCGhnCoqOj14Xf/oDcYQDxb3a7j9gJ0/QKQvUtDo06ZhcGNIcI6tm5RtgAug6nz4JDAmW6ZPaJyun0RJEGZoFTPnYnVY9RRz03ockMdiK0BBKLrGxzJnYkPecywkX7KKaLJMRcKPtI70LCUAKVNxZbYwx1opS50c8IZaTTx@2UmjXdZ0lNepjarqc21lgGZE2VxPaEogxognLxOTmBL3oY5X2wtDBWer3uO2YuNL/yhY2tM6jKhW3fGhp1KLsSRzCTdTlKUkVKnxJpZ78p90@6lkhuAiw1IOCnWuvVu06ye1K4Fn08SojnHaLC7GqmuKCCpoU5xpoyAuZCBkn0hBaY5P8drY5WjtzznjBVz3e2MO8SJdUG8dBBBgA7JnmUY41RWVkUkEwi3tNzosayk1@IIClw1T9LJeDI9X3SKAUq6UFDsrMemg2TLGg@R34BKsb0x0FwXcberA/Z4OKj5wNJlWIfwmkZCoCxEE8@NJFDtDhDSEI@oS/Iuh@ElJJRBDLMutNiTjd5cRwYiAH3Z925QY8tB7oDyhCMPkA4bE9UH0DQQmBdkixeEp0Qui0U6tYGgYGwdg5WljgmdALsb0PQA5@fKBuA5jcNAbLyTzNGekX6BoxpnDWYdBsc0nY2APLgXrGsgzQHiY/ABBROZUP/zgO9lTp9lJa1QWOxjN7qY7ypb0ldApN8qt/YkLPx8Z0JCw/rAZlu6PZjoA6AXjg1B9G7XGPsBoYKSeD6QouvjDTlKweApe8NY4uH1tGkQCdmjWRpI5HnrBUOhjtQlYNsl4MmQ9eOyAOuZLpAlGMmvpQ4AZ9cSF14hyEIGXgkrshByAIBkxtToTnygaoDA50OzOwScxdzZnC7yQeh68uA0nzpQdqkfJY2ZURsPtJisRE6YjZVRSNiiN@OBwRWjaiw4UOPPO9wes@6NlkTsRFmEgWDOVVZ0GXDvjjhHju0siRQqMooWQRZ9eDsAJ3aETDEMXCHbRZ014pSjJoI2A6oBPR/wb@j7Y68K44TpDycdGTBFOXYv9v0DG5FF8d0L03e4uWM5HSDLHvRPJUxB6U465vRagcgtasPXXuwMGLC@x@owcr@ZANalkn0PCCa57yDwnJdAhJui4E8BAAlIhopK9T0ixXtAVI4u7G5KWEBKIcME7LuCCAYMGFXNZ8i8LWbzNThdzyWCzWdGVhBK8dwuGaQ5nhSjR3DKVuwbC0W7Zx5j3xAEePR1yzPgbU8sC60Tm1O5FOcVRHYZ@8Y3gLSlKDlzNLbMrum3uS978CDgKdgayHjINvWRZxIhzDcCYVoGggIwwfDDoWXfOSJmNyVCQb5xtZCw4bqOy9P1h65zzsgBwWLzlbrjjJC6sxfEcCEHDWKtaaN4H4ylNJTqS1mIaEwlfjmZlF87pp26TK6trSWryQaMmGtrm2DaQNMmmtJg2iSTRCaEk9FEITJkQt8mhUC3k@RVM4x5Kp5gd5jiaP/WHKf0ZrWaO8noTTV4a/gWoZ5hxABoCV8QT1Ks19EoikLjHAoqd/qLpd/BUe@o65rjoBI@0890bg9qIUfVAA3nuCgY1JB5ub1ORnUXuAsQBrrDlJtsNbOtk9Zlq5duXSUzGFqs6fUOFArSS43kgetMgA0Rm/mqpJ6IYjMHzEennswm11OpsgRiHEgi4idlMa3z2k4lDRgNU61WEio1qJ9md@hSfNOMJopRVUE@kOEBXjuVlC/LkH5HPBHTSQgrJjMgutWTSaiZLlaCR4XGvrRQQQfPv8krZiedjlH3BqkU7xvDKbih0LsY/HDy9i3SLh5HJ8Iwa6JzLm8cACj7dggro@c1oTX06vQZ0tGFND51@lwq2sHH7pO9mDGl1vr0YG/3eZ2SGereKfAU0gBhFeCVoVbcngzUwJr0jNgyGCAbYOrOcoJzB5j4oNtlksMITOryTMwNF122IjagNcR4OkyyRotF8IaQ352FMlAk5E4hb@NfumGWOPjSPEVJ7gHF3jl6sjBFNjoFfoJ1PQuZb8nlBQCrss4de/SKZIwq2ycZzQYGE3AL@MteNBdgO7aEtDAU55z5hPiECECQG3JbyEmYCzAYcd@cgkgcx/mUgPVHjhW5/x3HBuHUkF8QNRQYEHKcrTLkpfz/IWek5K43653A6YNxbOldoPeL0bUE1oIIgQIpynIfsXYj4uvCAcnxd5URWKmubmP99UySUyemN8TqBVkCRwG3D7WKQipO7lCt7bMucLkDqGljavpcaoUefoRBHuteSkQ5aYvLGYhlyCNjpsKZO2JgnS5I@AbwyujLp0vYrn1muo6NlSzvQtRAimrYBtciX1a9gEZbW/vao9X1uyxyqLEbzupc3c7Her1yux70LtuxnIHD1gEAUVOWOWLv2zjDCVKOr4@hR5lvqYK2Bg6I@os4aBjRnGkxF8mbOkIqBC@/hlGALS/0DGBFmY/2v9oFNkQtZLOQ/9CWpSsq5Fws18uIjl02AwhWASzEG2zJr4zx8MJdQCfPCeZNfJo8pI7JZ7J0YCEhV0EPf0tB5zs5d4F@Hnr1QtOysu@STICTd/Ny9ULpF7gV3m2ghPFrzugaVsVCpDcafNa@SLhaygLdiqYKpP7I8XXlCxlIND5iyCFLJhM8JbmWVCQJnwJ5Ma3BlJ5xpiCVmsU83TW6S@OeGkZXQV8c3FhoWFo9oeeKqmnBZdMDisnfYR1EIa@Xf5BOI2Gn3EVp80zDIH88nBgxozt0mNACEWO@ZAIMEEOQlSWoeWAAUS6JggUrQjHfmYBY1zMsc2T6@zRnb9kou8hEvGWkWoHvDtCbWQSHpgEMOZ9wmA0yOK8@G6PsAYd/DpScYgURX@ZV6ho9ZX0W21PHcUGu9JhKcwpaVPWjwENxvHFP9qcQAQ@1S@O7F47zzw4e7bYPt44f15WJ5yqW2QEa0TPaIxBmLegOKy7MG84Q7gLumLYzMqFEYZRvT63njuNz5gEXDu53xTFgGMeTR@0n@9vPt55/O8gcjejmaGLpmMdq4hpAFMcRwdwaTdfpOMBb2JOVMQFzcbB98CSM5bPPn@xvtR/tHh4cz0XzemKZujpVxqeDVQX6DEGYKmd51R9YvcUVHRJTF2YRAmKDMleNgWzKJAmeErrxRFEqk9EDWWQcHiUJZ4F1nOd2maZmK5VeRy@XjWKvm8@X@nq/18trarnQLxe0QhYepWLFYO8IXJKMKc3cgInPiuAEEqYBmaeXKudDDgdE0S5wLBdL8xX53pK5bqFglPIVvdKtVCq6VurldK1cMoxiqZ/PZo2imu13ymo5d2vm5rKBrNXMNqIZIOh1OFlAnkD8UvBa6A4888DrnbOepmnFbqFfyWm9Qjbf61SyhXKvo5b0TsXI9vM5VVN7XU2thmFxRhWoxBAaDLlKG1jT0EtSwVOMhYPpfBPTKmO4DB0QnEQOScw4XEZGwSHwyKPHJFhExqnZwL2A7uESMk7RBO5FdB/hAvKMkyVr5BgAlgkQ15FltxM6VtAxWkFeWFsFUhnQz2X@qwMFMV@q2SuM/BzXoOfKd6mq5H7m9/sLzho5n0o4lFkz5xw58xXoxbXfoLA3vJYCR/HlKT6@cr00vhteS4Gj@Ao8PlzxXh7dNZ9loFFkRYoMV8iXxnXNYwlgFFOJYppfVZ/5lclv1ZJ6kNZS75WBorgrFDdfLW@/5qsV7WCxHLGZd5Bj4MSeOMA/PzFx3r6/0GNikQTeignhNMLiRNLMR5stkzDpbPn6jjAfEScGpn3qkOAcmdpZWS1gLFEUo1PrZsg@iBr0WAC9kambPnz8GnX69FgCgIPu9Zk58qBpz2Doh6FWV57TCydAl@VgcSp3IfmO0Z@AFKR0TBvNd4BJlTJB9jsdcxUo1ARuPgjfS8Cq7PkEJFFNzstqKPbi0gnQbD4Pe7x/QIAdnYS4xfl/tlD5/sT1IVTw/s/f6UEj3GyioX5BsmBkaNvGOeFHf2WLBUHRQo/lrTsb9aliyHRXlF0dl1x1KzIsj5paX5KGujtCkStobkBQfAAm3IJrPOd8LiZ8L0@kyqiSF9cZmG2OWHcJNMFeWxLhiZGQbTl6j6qBi8KmQYFcbGzeDMaUC4VzDA@MPKsSWrJywWZbBfzhxJ/wJ@4OuKsZzTHet3XRADJb0DuqASyy3jGNWxrd1U8nPUcCTo@KjBkrLoGdlZ4m66S@pZ9yYxuNy4vPC@iagwHwE8F7Fdj5EGQbEkqVc3rdhReePfHGUgcay4eOQzbqCqNbUnAt/lwFYgb75yLD6lozLXrco9Ej5CJ0AZaOKhq3NElzlWZeq2ZL71ygqD78eCzDBInBAZpT76bT2RwOe9Ha7/xWpNXhcayk8JXK8tB8MxWvkmXilcI3UUl8ApnKHGyruqNhYeAyR7olab0540qKHk4dz0xLQGneRupaugeo5QfNYZxB89HjNnTHkakLYpc7M92C7LPshFsAVq0mB2Qr6NVdxzI97NrWKgp6fQFuliZuZ6PH3JS0uaxie8QzeUMpMi2nC07Xx6XcFYh2DyrHV1FxnXoOc2RnVaV1nXO8V7IWQ@fM4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs7t0ROl178JU3A5Ej@X1eLo0X37XWuq@2AfCKY55Ae2eeO2ZluOxI3reVi0DF4Lx53KMnq9BU7clWg@aNy8PFmRqzORglnVFu@rWwLGK5YGiw2Nl40/cPo4Jwfu@1C@iXqp6N/UK@SPHVoP3SrJ/qrind7UdLU24uGg/Z7xlBF5GwoJFydUFBEkCd@IsL9xetkwhZYXLy6sawO0Oz/WL8P0bjCyrajccWcYXxG8D@4cBKmUw@C7nwX@T1PK3p9a7H3m6EW3prkLMNe6pZcBARs8bTcq0rPqRIdRs9v7Eqm9NjImxlFYddF4buL/9Fink/pnKBsVIBLOdOCOEc50R1NtAfrxXrnEMR9utBEa3TOjkd3I6S@ndGHj0MYrch2A4RMPNgAN7Ml5o3AUpzn5@e80Nx2HPdnoLmUSfj6VI5bv5qQVG3jPovlW44sIgrm3Vc9lsNuBv5uavFyy3CV25KOxrkz8XEiaXWcozWJwNceeMy9OYTaVC05unnoSTmvejTtqqGQECrlQU27QN/wKfq5pkGbXtOI71MU0IRLdnIv8GXCku/NzVlDd4o2A3GJvNfXg4c9Lpr5r14ANSIJ1C7aHgfRs2zE@93quZJVyyhl46uGa9fR5obiL3rlRgmKfJJb51wlrNeAYzKqpclku39kjOzjodw9L5a1rM3xZfRc7dGl/EsgR8Mq1t4XoYXwGbrajGr9Gt8QVUltkDIWdojAyy3iId6L3XEy98rQSaOngv8ZZpvXFVuLEJhMLG58Jq2xwr5Ts2iGW@7g4MlGssXBUPXFcR53BWfWnl7o/0gcHPVd1GPWdTHbh1mEuDM@PySY8q33XWhWB868ftqACd6dS48ML30gifXnShPSeju6fqrvX7Lm1Uuqujy8rSxYQ7eEV76AztoTHkO4Ei26ruARjp8xNxtxUC8j8YdhnRp/ldSvM1azmWdZ@aRfrIqaXj9JfmaRfPafUg6EfFe6F3wCN43TkFCGM9VRAN@qv6zdCYwJDlOb4zNiSyrQK1cLKIP1dR0XBx5zedhbp1hgBqJHz/pvHfKZsOdMcfj@nVHlsTjx4UVKLjdcuaco@SuQ9WmD7fdsTx1hg4ne7QvCtLHUP3bfNUCWeEuPVWyXY8Vwsmkx6hs2yZUHnuhYzYUJ/3P8LX/qomDSaX@LAVGZa3cZXtTFz3AmvCdxzmWc75jD4s7p@IpnH56gMaVuUgWBlc4k3cAO6sC3eQ3bIEEiwkrkQwYsKR4ZaMLDAs6soZpYXtnXO9I5fjj1V80bXyU6bm1m8/Zko02PZAk4Pm3MwtuC/gz8Ji9NLByh5OBt5Ncscn7HvAYuFjaUtvDfBM87WG5o0KI5BuB69V9a1ZCm7fhncbWm5i3Lq6Urh1eYXgVEvSHRNebXhBG05WTptZ5tjjTyb1taUMw80l5JtQF8vF5qB9ekafr4Wg6S5Ob@S4eIgIWAqp6xpeF6fSkSJz/olTH9sZAGWWLDYDDmGXFuHmqvXS5o9GPOnLZ8ZAx@2VT0zcaWktwQqI9fri9V2Rfmuie@a3Jo5vLI3v@gL2XdE91Qdm9/FCzYeRhTUa7MHjrwW0R6eblX8@ND06vxEabplzQiTjaIt41gZ@f5m0dm26PjoYffu0yhyjFOz9ZtI@C/eIRwZcMEB/fWlay2binTHJjRdkum0S3vRpZjZ4L8Wq5ZsAbkv@fDIaT7zgtTx12qczP0U9OiV379wEsii9AWrMhrrlL5/GnpuZBZ4rGCRnxlVc@Fem5QzYV@UsAxYNBm1kypcg3DYM14e6Dz3CXoLAlPY9F0px0kNyecHeAE4YOSaZtunfPsHj@zrISOEbC8MHGzyFqDzBp/zwY2OQjpfXyJNbORgY2y@6Fh6K/1hJgJNdwMIjOrSOxujc/DzeB8kYO0GE4ehiG@fz8tqtiz5VHFIde@JLuMv/tjGleOuYUmXTcnEONVjqW7tPPxfnMYS2v97FhxogCE4862JmWrnx4BrimTYwa6tp8SJ0KE08MkilwXPaqHlHmK0xnp4ikv/IWSbxHF7A6HNvkQkGkMnokdHFlcc7037mPAXWDYayMRDd0XMDtwxcoyXLA2KwJ05Xt6B@encmc0TRLhkrZsK1PjY60L7WzLScF1sW8SPd11fwTjRxSBJgZLoTV0yrY7ivaUZwzrxKqF3M0GNjSmLIaoThvVDyu13OcOO03EIfub62440dx@ZPIsJZeKlPbyc2MDzQ4/4r7jLuX14Y/ZYKaYulPTjj202MHj@4t6q4rtFxLP7EIqwgB7bJNxforml4yhPTnkzJjUnAuy0Xc/g23qxcwmkObwid7dwEGTva3Yub1fhWYe@aJAUs8Znu0ZL/cplmYSfx/XcVDXW36@DaWWD4yJWzuSNhd9DxaKs035rQgUaZAkHTu5NQr8AdWbVGnRE9Vsokcy393OjgkbsOnR/19ekyJnLx6FjgeO3wVkjSsOMXWeoQpB7x7oHsusi2WOPmmB5E0M@XokmY3DPT6L7VxTtoadSLaC5Z0UmiXdqRFjfBAZtjGZI/xD2Wiu@vIhjPzNNJ7x5rXeECymRk4Jr14srNSqRyvCFhhLN8lT4iuK4RbN3GXYLQ9UMzUl1payXKYvTwP9j@TIGBuV3M4wn@yVQaADm7e18AZH7i2sHrPmh36Hh@35wejFGNk@Ouoi9YrAIEgRfvDmhaX1UIaE97YvH5jsHcjq5Rj@Q74Ab7DpgsIuG@IRn2mUQqjqbhcqWrh3pkVrbh9c2h6h27Q8@9aD0QPKSxR29l7B3uPzk4lsfekomQ4CgKac2J9Ct4meCQFLiZbnAQ25NDFVDBiTIiEOHZBnDUu90JzmVAJcuMAFMpPZ0WxVgQ6rFzzkaoXwYDeXQw8tQc11g2NGJVDGEMIHg8Gp5iCZ1t1JmWzzJRrHEtC8ATQi1MjBrrm2HUW55nDmzIQpgDUpCDyjO47h2PAaPph/E2myxxOa1mq@oVqzOhKrCTE55jvCiR3emYtNs858GbCf2knkhKUjKRbNlVlk1G4IYFAtZScH0BFjKLryDDUf1yzVcOqa2KarPGlYMA4UPFO0Pd7lkG@9ymhUUov8tVXHD9Kce4YfaXf9wL9BGR3q2R6ekWVAiqFHNGxtA53@TphtU1HuuozwjjAFnZ4to1pJ0tBoKa3x1yNUTQXJ/vHZcD5SaB/jKwHPLprigXHHNwzQ0PavocMXhuokN3QcJRqLBQIAFMRjYMuT1/6MnsyKQzmBN3dqoi0Opm@y5OrPcybJ/1DNybSEdraR3JcpxTOm6DOfnlH3OVLnTANjj4GCZPqpzmUsRztCrpUel2nQnkOozkreE6AUgKKxmk4wmu2pImMXIX8dgp6ZoBbJdCTSuUDFe3srN1xKRdlkQdZagZoWb2U4mt559@0cye1N@zkWL85@8o4mVQccInUqXoCRkWgtSuELHmvQvgPfNNMiExFXiC0eljM@Dxz3l7oH41jmR4ADnEMccZh90GmUZSDhVhY6B0IYVmaudQ5cqIFG0RwhrnpHKFjrnZSMVI0ZsHHQysIkXNe109kZrwhUTpyGcFSBDV1uhg4qq56Dwuqg/BIIkpe8eGiGTANaqFLNh4RVqosWZU3w53rufmTxQoj4zOhHbVnmmyVqhTcRLt@kaDTDAqOag5qvmyNdWyUmta2j0BPjio1FZr@klW@xJq3XEh1AMFe97us0eXCbmRfffO0y@YIFwla/wEBJCJxOXh/uHu0fHW8edH0ApXIWnb4@egQlqDWERHG4eORTq5oF6QIf0I@hPZZmQQtT6KYmz@EBqBBnUtSEKCG@dI00LoO4IvC@8Zc/43AQKa1jdZLBoZAAt0QjasNSz8ZIyaxVgQNtCORFhm4viBHSiqGDxnsoSWUlUJrA6VJUFl3bOq2OrCbnK3@9TYnbHcXm2bS0GwxqL0mpE/L@LSKrj6Byn3WPe8//Zy81huLzfB3FJuAI1cwzB7W/tPPn@@uxgsHOSJ6tYrheD0JSfO2NM4UxuqgyKlB0FAXIitC0ygANwaDGZcKaXhnxtQrIA4dkc8MGEo5V@IzRATaqaOelFPAi4klaIcIH@DjMj1w6HAcc5lMRyj56K75EWMiMCeEEUdZlwWgpjjpN9TxissBsYaVFfY9Q6JiAf0OunNsz@ZsMdh0XCMnni8z60YqqJRx2PwnxuVQpN2wqYsGM7UEyYxDW7LsAdQ4BBWrPExiiV4RQgJnnchyi/qZYQ89V7rtPZBhx6CQ5UwSlv62AuZwTh75vhGlb2ZOKS4ISQmEX9BKkF1rkaVmpYrByWFECBsAn8djlsU3/7eUR25M86aEX2fx7mJjQMVAHGNpsHRat9Fzb/8zCtXLcir3Am02IVDJc0feIHWqohL8NiZ6Zkg/VIj9JHHsYBSYmmCgqNWXFLZwbYsD3iSHgzfwKH4ONQCcyLTSTx@HE@ymRAHnJQjljHDhBjCevWbWs1gKD1HeegVD5wgOIrZm4szubEmSVBzA9MOVeBWUScuic5V5rsT3GjXSN4IEmahSiZp6I@sOcAl@h1bhvLhd/@A63Rs@WD@QWCeZrfB9tuBrQ/m3wl9VBVs/yyyaWD7Ibe9VLDJbiqym@Uz0kmw8uwiIOdD4UbBkDCEyoCpQFGTY3N/sX/IvC7qmMUGHenTubZCMhPKKcwcAWacUUMjOE9h1o6zeFLNLwBPALkASZDHQbaG0jPckxTqNKsqCmYcl0Rk2vFoTPkuBFJx9maCqj2BE1OKhWJeVSCT0lkYIWldGeABLB6hKFaBMMbOzHH9VafLNjY2mOB1dcuoF2scQZSE/jInvIoymgDYGJcWmgzCQJBZCPBrBMFSCT2tihgUR7OkmkTC1nM4vgFLmCIDgIjobId6GoDndIKqAmS2jalPbNNFKAUB1badOZ2@YUQSRMTjRgWU1/vk7FAVzuPN9VJ5vhmEFwh2hGBVYRnGNl@ylt@yTwJFpAyw76dL8NcG8z9Zop2UYxbqobmpFjN1XaklloY9PLIdnA7dg9yylKZoOUUtinMYKgRRQX6xv7@DKKGHA8XoGuZrZ@xt7ezuf3ZweHRDPRJBJq@DJVmysZFuSXKmeRIZklG@Fyt1e085erq9F1blfK5mE5IIMdthej2by1K7ntMVqb/g59dupk0eNxJSs/eNmLZvSXu0U/tm7DNfZQ5whx@fuZFqSry8ap5sNFp2/Eby75apvI3L64hcYGp5pPA2eT2bmMVIvf0xqrf35PBwtoons/HInu@czs55Bw5zHhw8jAUoQExWQqhVxBMycMBngGYKSTSuX98j0sdniUgRaZSjOcjjUBM/dq2Z/rxAcdxQ94aW2YnBAN5DZYpc7Uuo1yRSGCN7Y8v0U2KMpkDqyAYBEUsF@vin1alM66gpUntLcWXYbbrowvjEGHQCiC95OPGG7NAZz81tPTJC03PgRtijCV9kM9hnkxHA9en13EASawB/IkFgqKhklFUuVUPPClTRTdOo7g/Sa6JCuqDg8qhXSE1FeWhMe@YACHhKzEBP/0QFtio6LI@FJvV0dhJoHK/hT/HY0nyVfpRGwukscr2py6bdM6YpVLFTPQH@FN2T5y/OkqJwAwdILeJOqEjtmn7EsCPqftAjZroFr3W2SqSE/5oCy0oF1RThuX9oFkjxyHefgBHGp1R/pI9ZakKKOz0mM7KmWik74/muyKQG1/1hs3SapGp4kQdwzQjaJxMhDkvhPGRKqUProKtn9/D11hyzpirLJ2CmRESWwBm1HRjKcS5KjIGUBEGqFG0d25ZVMUcce2WOeRAG/WOkSYyh9sol3qRvkqapHawLKjVrPJjTwDTrgbxWK5Vq0BqLpKbCAC1uUnlZgWiXkJCQS4X6DY5xQ62hPnZU3I@z@EAWHn7TsG0DKghwZqTDGKxPAMlcMRN@gCMz099NKcR5Fh8H58Iho4t6vXeTlxYu9SaUGk3O1K5gTH3VwkG1HwyrF8r/qMhK7TKVsOoXCjA6YiOVGNbVdG49nU7Y66mEjUP9gwc4p3OVAE6iLYOINAUgKWGJNcBn4DzqCbuW0DdSiV5dW6cQYAUh7RICvPcU@TKhXymJBzBSZ8DF5Z03lfBINWRWltUryB/2kISSAZy5RE169PUNTD5hptOYBznRxgy8V1pHaaLZrSOFpo9qATeqDEZBd7tGVaOWuPHtEV6BgXPQ0EDYNSTswXb8dgg80@qdW@a3gvfgCX8TTzwx2mRpePPsv7Doc3/CEtC7JGnt4oo4uW5OqMBpCioRrRldFIGY/PrXcbXIhFRis5g7SycL2Ro81FqJFdgniZaWj7P4QxDXlXXBFS5bj8pnzOhrxTeS1NT78puTw9PDwy/FVioZ3zl4Kah5AC2xCt33vUpMW3Gxj7vi8XUlFlfW1QclRXn16hWwu3A1G3JjHko@EZtS8qSZKoGlUSqtZ4rl9czDZJuyIqY0TTxipqmwljn2ej24nSF9AycV5xfb3MS0wAB/FriNpn3uNssMBwlcw7Ch111wVb0QZ62Srq@n89pDuyZrWe2Xv1i7ylwetjd@@d2RYqzh6wBfP7h6iuYjtfDJ2ton29v5fAYqj5sPvzr89tbWVv5RpnDYLGzmpezaxl/9xdqapm1oytqJ56knyebpl4KWzQvyL3@ePDz8VtvzsP3wyjEVjPgsw62yQoGdsrdwnfYZ/sn8tjdn1tHc6b/FARKY5ToRm2SykEsevUxicd/GVVWNX9CvTdWwxtTGZum//OjgTdyPNzTlhQtvP/4mXizHuREMYMuFtrN4I76BYMWr@IVSr9fBWPov/w7CNz6DeNDnYgMejUIYV/Ei3pDqFORdvFEEg6ppkO7/853vxOKNKSJCY3@PaQ1tneOKWn6gPmBTfrFWXC3nDx6Cc3iFXtHFFFXVWmF7zjU3Nm3kPITCQ7syZ84tavcQM@IswAYyfAwcfi6puPbw1SNFacBQi1e1@jBCNYWVyoLjQHeuge1J5P5cluCS26G9hlYpKEK8XM@0efIRrsbnDNcKHD1ZUPbI/pFwu3j99f/11z/@6x/R78d0/6dYPNwIITXPGieN8GJCA@kTC2xPbfaUX7YNf7hDK7qgA5hsNitLPN5o4IP@gY1M9L7mFvg0IgtBzILcAhfQDEo3Fn@vKMCtwHXWWLhYQ2GRmYrAc02Gp3Mlm5UNUWATrjX40R@uyIrPNXIJnAnk5rXGGrddt1LfWLwZb56cTDfY7ZFcj3N53PGzWFwC0pBOPweeMUDm@1yfwy3L7cAWIXU8Fv8HvRoxFr@E6yQtXV015ZfpWi34AytVi2x4cRPk6eRKkjZeNtLpJuWt2QgyuSGdNGTW5vmlx8sNiDe90dyoOzt0y22sIymZd5JF5@HJy0ZzYzGOIJqHD9PYmR9CPI3ECQMmHmr2auOqcdXcuLra2ID/Bj2vgje4Xm3c@NNrdtVWAEXX1Qk2equpNFpKK2jQE7DLSgNdZKUFhga8Aa7ZjMUvEV1Y84SUidWlplosnEiMusQ60Cmlqq5rOaUw/aS4q0GP9xBcEwRlHQ3vcGQC/qISiyOXXuHMeoUcXn34@v/Au/Xh638DVsgafrWNfDtv8PfkLf7e@Pg77uLv@Rv8Hb/F33Mff4ce/p528BeL1xkD5iixmbWyZ1n1VD0Fg8mywJsOs0O1h4NB1mDZi@wFy44ctQcmA35ZMJnZPssOWNbO2qoKnmDwWdZHUx9eA/j1IRYXfmY2i5FnzxikYuEQQ0p46f2uzcRWrMmSrwzgamRVzspFs31SKI7fNJMntbjSaimczWNavkZKl6@uWLu9@@xRu60g4reeOgez/8HBaN5663904Dw9cEYO/A8ODp62gGA10g/T0kO46o30RvDajDdqm62qhPgrB5gcVzY2W42chOZiGrBSQ7f0R16zGOHdWGvFQAp@8eK89uIF/s/Pauc1MkTWF4G1/SKAiXwxFHeACF5Az3zReqG8IBtcZxQv2dB4Dp6hiRuUF@fg9IIBZx79oTrmrf8Af/P/X/@nn7NU80SEPnB5tZGiS8SfKF5eXV4Fz4aYSgWW1Ab80AHsGOTyqoFGAroEUzMlnohXV9wNnilxg0fYwDQ2GhR4BgiEIh6lSenyR@of9o1p86uVBN4IZNZUsODWak2zWbHWAZdo1l1/R2s3Yo12tSQ6uN4GcpoqEkQhX6up69ys5bVaLR9YSuVarRyYE6lU5ebVyG6qxWJVy@dFsVbLBrAgktVCI0RheHq3hn28Fhcxs7zjp7I470dfW0gKVeHBg1TwfY7N8RgkdLWSffcucmq3e6bbbqN77t07oS3gBph6pQD2bPndO6A5SRFk92cOX3pNSSr7RGtQChUQyrV8CbyZqmizNIe6p/u@m3prjjMC7rHzBJE0JGezjttK/uqH3/1uK1nHLRHkmlcxAkyFFTY2ivlGo5gHc7EMBRcSfI9NapCuqOJVQhF4cUH2TsYDL7VcEsn1Kon@LL7BNhvQUT282OVVnNqP5QtiqnNhiJfgErqplQp3ZPliqpyuBL/6msga6yz4NZvNXDq/Xlp/eAIszeKFBLWWVJRk7VKvq1f1S72Ks0NXtW6ghx/PvugPHuQqUJXlbK0Va7cfbR1vtfETfrj2DUMfQ0eizzFc1xy7ySZN5RUqJ00s1omitJLJau0hNbtaLrB4shZASkkg9qxcofLHPS9m9vEY3JTivXavx8dMLeVgVIVBNTamjUilLOvhWq7LnH5/DRyh7VgHl909w7LCrxecO67VOzd7xlosfvhka2f3OKNtwBit7W3tZLSjz7fjKloLMzt559D@fHfr0cHnEODwye7W0e6n@1/sfn4I7l7s9VvdMHRjYhjn7cnk/A0quDfaxhhcZ1fb6Jqe/vq1PqaL1ThpPj//8NPvf/jp//ThZz/88LPvf/jZj3/19Y@/D/cfw/1D/v7hv60U8Pmrr//ZH334w5@B43@C@z/C/Ytfff373@E32f8c7r@cc/vz4J6D4zeLN9bxAowoa@X0evoh1OTD9HqlAphBPhsxSO63f/X1j37@q69/5ydw/4vg/snN@3d/sfz@8fdW3xjuR390O8wP/x3cf8LjCmF/@IfcDd834P@Qw/3OTz783r/n/78Kfmj82Yff@3N8BJZ/@pO/@ssP3/0Pmlb@q3/94fs//PC9H3343nc/fO8HH773j7UPv/@v1ez8448@/PhP/@uf/cl//bP/hf5/TM8/uc//w0/@6d/8n3/zf//NnwX3L@D@92D6xd/8B0Dmv/vTn@L/R3/6d//xp/j/3//l3/3p//p3v/2vyPAH3PD//ot/y59/@93v/@33/vnffvfrFc/v3/r8@h7uX/93cLl/Pu8Tz33K9bEuX/9G@flvqY1ZKoAD9LEBpgGXu31hsBqLZVk2eEAn/PE/@fD7vwW4/XsACbb/GWzw5xbw@gFZvvxywS9Ncx1S@ssvQUj8MhAWv5wH@gFj7xRgxLMP3wHAl@TLLxZBQaL/G0IBGAugQrCFxAkE91Fy5199/c9/ju5RSHT9rfn4sqHrHGwCgd@FRfwBduaoGPOwP0By8OGn3/nw83/84ad/8OGnv40jgpSvZLYyMKDfPpMKgIV7wCFg8T5wAKiioAgS/VpMA8PaBs78xdT0q1fQCGtgAjlrPVbIgS2mNsisohkCgvy/TpFM0zhVB/c0lq@ADQzgNCUDeKXBazuNH5ZOx6Z18CNQ/CI1Q2OjjLN2OJVQh3gxEA@TaZdBhGHTbYoFQtbTz1l7vT7lAdPo0KAYGGYInZ4Lqiaky/VHkGB9@ohhXBh5OvYK3q/qjXJ92sDo3lMWII70NiQJUPjB6/S08R7sdYoT4GPTR@8hK@V6Ot0og0udikqpZdqUplqgwlHZ04zKje6M4V7GzYeMfSKoZYHPdUBVsgAan@kZ9CZNBW6Cfyu9HhSH/qGR7nUMD@00pfrhbtx/E50pfAAA8UoSboGDW5IwNw/Be8qjSlOy8ErzGKDm0nyqlEUOxKakY2lq3zRZIH3Iw8dcG3yAxuiwOIlEAkwbDSEntA9AcgQRzT2ter7u4hIdsY9VJhQrAjrjfiLcbpY4JAFz/dE6PFX4767R3mAqSW09lkjiTEWShSlJ6ZyTd@K8EGEJybZOBUgTIPsEfPB@@BDMUEP0nrnF4rNwXOCgtVimFvNMjKXo60kiVlLXQD6IxZ56g21nCsx@RhAyahHXWMRgfuS4qmGHie1Ws/D8tlOt1t@r@VIM3mSf4Fecgu8JQdPht6zljQ1sgsalRJM4aARmsRhrNIKlZabGGke7xwB@fMBULSszEBQu8yUtX8gXtFyxWChpar5YyRcL5RwQtmK2oGlqJZ@vlCulKyrZQ6ANmep6p7DR@Ec3rv/hHy27lrviFWt8yaYyzVBfxRpWnW9vTOASs9DKCjWaTaJ6TDSzGfxpuRw8IY8ZtVA6WVuzLiUscov21F3iIj5kM3Yp4Yz4N@BisW/E2DfACS5IAxfZWLAtYv@gFiyB44cY@TK4oBYAj8RYC/CIxwZNenl5OXfH4mtffeWzRgO4fWl/LxaHHjBk4ZqvZPbkoUyfT@xNXIN8B4w92v9i/2j/4Jn8aP8ImO9vMy2XlWPxq6urfrRSQVaDHRwcxJD0gFCVUzH8VZdNJhPy7YD9aqrHxvNXbRzTNEnLSTlVUnP4v8Og4f/@8Br8NXxCqJwW4weuLDyVEk5RVWLv37@f0oaC6r7tBzsLtHwZ3VkM@8ADoO8PVG4sFGfGLBo3guP2jRgtoDYB405i@G2u5klsQ4k8j1HzwTNoOsB1mz3BfcS@w44dvl912@iugNgZ8q/M77gOCFe/Ocy2bp9yr0cmP4IdeT3WUQerNzL94QqIz8cjPIFmuP/dYtgddSCDuJTCAbbh4VqOswygxD4/XFHKp5HGFNyrQCpTAPz5/qePj@fex7tbO49jRbZ98OzRtVchACqwJ7t7x5G1xH3DoIUoim/vPnly3Rq8gJzWSJ5eY4VSJgOjEjzwnaGL3nLiZQiiyqvZFd3XQVpvsvxJzb/aVOvqgwdqQjl8gjL@oQs1bzkKSPHvpY0vpEa55hpT/33anrDPKwVWzjV2h/jJWbe@negDNR8YzRMU76GaaKXkKW6ZrKj8/I/pxegYHn7fCr9l58fwzHYPv2GN8y8d/Jj0ZMxWOsILndDomoMhjB/nTggQ6@g6g/tjLwg/L5BDdd3q4PM0yO2Gj7UEHNfpzT7LxmSiCFqlXChXclo5U66U8wW1WChkVC2jlsqlClDvrFpWi@VCRc2U85VcHoYX8C1USrE4kF2zrygwkKqCAO8qRGt38ZMMG/htC0ceNmJxPuvF3qZ0Edo1sk@YYEAYAT8O5vm0K3zdrAtaHo9s5FQGMeqsy@J7ezvZvT1B2EYLzsnvZAWhh5ZCOZstbQuCQT47MARqguDwMOAFYD63ZLPbO4Iw4RGgghdBGKJlt4gcviCYaNnZ2tvDdF6jRcPwAHbKfbjFCi0lALPRksuRiCAIb6LoAG6LJ5SnnO6iBdNEnz3uswN@gvBpmJ9sFmJ4zuF4DI/Dsm5tCcI@t2xtoc9nVPACz@o30bJFlyC4YAEkFIQBGAauYdiC0AEjoqIgdMHUvdDBDT9/gUo/bF8XhAteQVhFgjAlaL17KgArG7hjMo8fP9aHfs8Y8OvC5e8uZA18zOlkd6/z6aedwaDjXmztfvocfT777LH@@mLidgadIFinDZcDYcDndHRx/YI87rfburXU55vgY1/zaV@0DcxbW38DeQquASYyan8GPp@Bz3TJxWODawSgHby2R/De1jvkE17kQ@9ppyPUEFH9i7GBM33YZ@gj95mR3nWdGtqn9bVkKpm5aBazJzVyZqOUeJmtXaFvP0UfWESKKF5eNKf17AmINyUtOFaSElpTrWAKmbXRplopVNf0TVXLp6dV1N7r9JMsKambKfXB@tvUM3FTy@WrQmtzUxKa6smmpparxdLL9YkgiFV8buZK1bepbBLYUHyIzdLJZqkwF6JUSuuKVi2VxNoV1IQPw1Jn4hvtdip1buinooh5RZ4A8k/FZBdURLPWT00z0zrPFLsQa9O6WuPHzln2Rlw91Hsywa@Y8RgHEN10M1tFQpwS1EpZgPQVJSWKSI2QfsD71YtwESh6zRkWjPySWVXin0BUy0VRxgMKbaffps9AsVfzkMhix17gaSI6SRxu@iPBxKvGjpEjxwFAZ6hbqYNfXaXj5yAecl09jM9@qKVKLNYImNJD/gGaWmD99PGODHxqYEMNKvIefmzbcWX8SKy/4MO1e4ROxzCCyY8N3MrXDd12@BlfeXcKAgieY6hdSi@kq/kQR8B78zTwmEONTs3jgWFUJWP2mF5vgEnvsRSlz3TxnMrZbjTq7frIGI39C5CL@CoylCoM/mwyYtuMw@Lpo/DsRbu@DRWQrdmoTs1Aa2Ian8YaPVQWs13fvpxUkaW8qhl1@pS4EMcTW5t2fWJ7et84NFw8LLR/AMOygadyusNXrV0E3IHKvrySGi6zZ4XY93gdRUc/KEOXmKHAo13PXtXmc53SpUZHrA3qTQR9h48NSRBOJKn57gQErFqsAb2vdhHX696kw7@3l@2AbFWsTcFNLeVrQ9apd15Oa259DCIBq1lQi3OSDtNrBP/OgoG0Lbfr01lt5OpNDWSdbCaUfjTcCZbRspWMpsJICiMshIS7BPY83Crc4K@ibJSyUgJjQiY7zcpqRjXUDAiar8zeKzHjO7s2tEi2WsWGgUYlK7x1Jqa1dSvVc5i@IVEbQxevUcb1zJCNTXikINxzQ7cogChKLCW92SymC1lRrL2BXLuJVE/eFjfztV5qm7VFcADeAG6NFfO1fj31UlysY7GWWhPrnvGG6hNJBVXGeA2aI5D/vMmomWVrRTVzKbWlK0v3/IRa0qrNSaIpqVDa7LvBhvBVQziBprliMfjNL98A61EDt5AscGZlxm7M3MbIcFoGtKJa0WoBSGwcEKmUkMJvMfONp6lksqQlk2KyhrMOa@AeEDmiSEkgj8kH6qYA7I5QFSoayJVzxO1GFrgwVQSR7yrWM70xA7Eqfhm7urzamN9L8012caGnpdD6gLFBOhFjCi2ry@04WyOTJDdocmirvjV4vlULoLd2YvEqbRyb7fJhreCkrqSsfexafnqj8ZK/W7hvBVKNkfqgJjsJZEMtB2XuzdmhfN5ljNcq386hbKQbSismCNS3@XJguSDynLL3cdLEz3Yu@wFRqj5F8ZKl9Crvs80T8f0z07os56QGyY8pFn@fhhrBPXAN5X0choUrquhwp9k3X2kFqHrbCR1AFvWB@MEoUigIOAFjvGLjo8rL0svyy6efH3x@sMceZqvlanmuIVoPMxk1qSY32ENgXs3nuyCtvGNOQX1vf8Z33cVr8eo4mcsnc/PB6vFpPR8u86bURkNSNzS2CRjKqkCX@mpRyr5rcHRrkEdRA58Pv/WT/HSjDHYNGMQq1GQhrTUa6romxscfvv43eIzrcveLrScsiYfq//4vfq6V/v4v/iWtKSavauim5UpxgESjWizFLy/Hl5dXcHG/QvwkzvOUL4lg5uvdaryhBM5qSRXjnsRtkN1C3HsXaNlIadky@O0ccJtQhFqMV@KxePnpq3eMbYAY2egNBqZGJkVZEM0SVRC64M/e47TVe2ntFVAVz0souP2xgsDhXMt6o9FYp12RyUYajyNqBZrwb17VTvhcCEoj6zb9DG8df8bLyGHd88Ae2sC6vmGwQkNlIL4oyoff@n1NK/79X/xuS3zXftf@FtDZSqVSVLX4r29e8UC7kQZ5MWy@NbaKB3ulMt/jj@T7tcc/lR6eb6TPZAOfTPpqPPrWqmXapxAAOQMw4wdYgZWosnsepowFA/dbPN0TmDu6ZxTzoc278HBfOs4S4uFGr6ooA9MfTjp0mvHYvdj3D@ishwL4Y4LMT@aO5XSUkY5zDfTVLQ9EKYBAJe0TW4HREo9q0FdJkXtFtRVtUiAFReu1AayNxUqJ1RiDlMd49Lo17fcFOrNtWL0jY6yToiDwDw@27vcQDNVI0Ynw8DDyAmcVnUSmGjdYcodvyJfoSLlDDI2XDA8hUtUyUndh4BERAQ9FB0ebaK@9IKMNPzQthPvsAaLvoCbZEJ6@RT0LEH2aehYCy4gaWQL@oT5fIpam8qfDTOCsMnegfMysQaIzB0qIcuMyM6O7A1KRZqOSKUgrBc0qo8bMplo9yXCOs65SfdPZdxMV@gAbjxpeqCRYoaQ3tG@6wLSp5TndL8SyUcj5cqTrQU4AkDcInvVG/WB4csHpvCZ9SoEaCsQ/OfQLjv@jEjJSOgSIbwe6ctl5x/QJAAY4AsCQygDPBPEqyiygamcywMMW2Bdkxx0opudNjEKpnKcM6XiCOwQFJncBVFMCBd4KZQ4PTEelqPhDZhlnhkUqCYJso6YonXdKwjPcW4PKIZFVL4qEOlCVCyWFWkhVMtzt0e7ek63j3UcZJqkFBMcTb10ngk3NVS73TpN/35p4wwCNMAjvvnKnmOdInvIyyYdKUgyy/nC@2tPzGQ4jwO9s4cTgOJWsUzDXGOFHzXjEbKz3kFZlKIydDE7143F6fmrM9DArE9dCvAkrN@z58biAKI1pxREFPb8HoYIvxkMYLFjA4YANCM8NoJW0AmogoG5tHzASdZYQ5grLjr8DYZWkBlfKIOxY@JXDJOrXmqe2Seo7Okseo4Z1GOKJtK0liS6g2odhPfmJl6x1gXkPOQt2lpqIl0EJTLuPuUjxijt2ti/C9ktNgvM4AlSICOyxGB3Q@eVfJoHbiOLzrJQvXp7pLntbBwylHidzor5r0bnHVJIr3oVgb2XkQYJzcHW/FgXoOL0LGfUK2r2doWn1Um/n0xgDw2n2U@l0t17PiZeQpDsG4uSNgRgaKNKJNXTrL7iBhbTnpJRWy4b8yeu2cc6@fPrkMTT5c4OOuTdfnqwnlAwwuGINi6DXUwj06ODpoe56hivKY3zvRcJTCr9LEiQiQ2uPvGb2hHKfEbBoCvZCoJwDww9K721fHOuDZ/rISCX1JD9ghkmZ0Cjmhi5zKalmptMiFFFvmicLdVQXFhtXEC8HdYIauka/1oGKPq1defWz1ECs@fAazidRgCTqmkax@xCo7sHjWq2b@JXyx8dPn9STGzrDWOtLekUy3YmQAxCFEIZOzm@5rn6xgDpAVQirfH5GlBAGrnRSaCyWZUPRG0lgXFfm54lDmi1kWU7OELiXmmQCjHPrN5u05s6w4GJs1NGBD22f7h4LGQjrTgwRHW0c3i6IaHH1B/UwDY5uSCloCLw4Qph6Pf/gAblx1Sf1upbNioCatSuIzQPMTUXCj1u7cvV6LxVVpD42l6ha0GRN0W3vHJWNAwucLZQ2HReGiHoPeMgHHpCQOirUPjP9iwceYFs9VNvwgJ8/ra/l18sH5va3vqwcFR@lup3PVCEjvPYcGwQ1dzyfAVc/lzlbBDTW7XLsokyg4tGuroz1U0fJ97LdcraslnpGqWCUs7lyt2DkKh3gErv9fLnTq5T0UqHbUWBw8ymIPDLxO1gCR39Mtn@/ZFcxZmUQ/Pt9Fbj3XqHSr2jZXC7fKRd62Xy@X1b1XK7Y08qdSud2rm2WHxS6QrqLY8d1CvzJauYudoO2B6HF/w8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,@'_   7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  ####### :a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1& xxxxxxx \#184O@  111111111 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D//> ++++++::@         / 78"oo@" ;   L         R.----._        ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>>>> ">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~// :    v>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]x<  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>               #v
#- ! ++R++  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++._       #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;wW;_W;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;'//';{a=1}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@//:@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#       +
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$^
set ! 51.                         #ata=""[ 4];t}?1=1&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rext~+nu U95 83>Ehar Cr=B$f 16ge[]putsngt    
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8           \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3           \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

psPILOT treats lines that contain `:` as commands. psPILOT has `//` comment.

To add it I commented out colons on lines 4, 6, 13, 22-24, 28, 34, 38, 90.

There is not enough space on line 4, so `<` that restores the pointer in Minimal-2D is placed on line 7.
*Note*: cannot replace `>` in Surface with `e` because that code is also executed by MiLambda and Re:direction.
*Note*: second `/` on line 6 is also used by SNUSPs and `:` on line 6 is there for Chip, but also used by Wierd.
`/` is a command in SNUSPs, so adding `//` required a bit of rerouting on lines 22-23.
`/` is a command in Kleins, so `//:` is placed where Kleins do not execute – between them (see line 38).

psPILOT code is on lines 103-104:

```
T:251
E:0
```

`T` is Type, `E` is End (exit the program). `0` is for SILOS.
There is no need to comment out colons after psPILOT code.

Answer (score 3):

## 254. [DOBELA (dobcon)](https://github.com/stasoid/DOBELA), 11677 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1tc@Nqdhj4eZj9B/vlEcjbJEQCIMB3UqRaUku3dae7pWnp3r5zSTUbJEESLRBgA6BEtVpdM5OtWU/syjqTWdd4vPGdmcRZe5OqeFOb9aRil6s8X1OufPIPaOfLlmvL8w9mzzkPQIISKaknTtWCBPC8nOf9POc553k56Oje8Ne/juPFDh3rYmA5PvMNz2c91zwzXJltX7CHuukVtFwshlBb7mAyMmzfq8biTGXMNs7Zvt01e@DGfOfUsM23hgt@GmNj1xm4@oj5Q90Hiwmh2CPDejd657OuMxrpds8DyBxjhzp49ifdU6Z3PN/Vu77p2OCVZ@xz29JHnZ7OAMJwx67hU/QFBlF0TynMok@RsaeO6xmYfNfwPAcdS4xtGKOxf9EASxkgdNd0nmw9@/Ra4Apjn@qQs7FlTK/lRc2yF6bh9q6FUFX2xfHe3nVXjX1Tcmy2dzN/ao597nq6pV@PP8@2Jr6z7193L7CtgWHrTJMrsnbds8i2Xf1GkBJzDb3XNy1DNu0uk9jQsMaGy9CF9R0Xmsw3rHK2nG1vzUPKXQxbnntei7YeXkx3Bx54OmcGGA1oibFp9FjfdUZMt71zSEmtZOfwGG1lER26kEFANPbag9A9g3m2OR4bPveE4houeUPKzDLt0xjHvkPX6U26pj0AOAPqdTzxqUxerAvBGmwc4LCMBhanWuBgkIUjZ2RE28ID5IVce2Oja/bNLq8cY@obtgfl9WRmQtudm5bFeoYFAeaxdzPMc9jEizh1LH0od@UYVi6mwkanFjNZdzxm3AuKAVnay5aZMXJem@wt@FtDj03HI@aZI/D2u06/bxjsrTEeQnA26sV6TozB1R1fK9nMljAAxjagdDuH34Z687E67T5krcc6ETjIB@WZSqzbDlSfy2x9xLGhO76g0kM0sxB9x5HRvecYnp302bnjnrKO0dWx2JiYZwz6@sSCFM0@NgfggemxkQNvaESbQbYgsI91gXFjYrGlBcFkwuY1xtAxsXkdRBdo67CVz10d8MP1gnb0zRFgh@knPWbonokUC4J4ht0jzBjPaJkDpY02OjszoeNBVUxcitszXEJ9ipdhKSBKfYarqXPX9AEjsBRb7NDQXXbsGobI8dTwuvoYsTSaJCTmYAo@FkQmxNzYSO4e7CUBQXkIWR8DQrq54299FtOZXGeJdg3uuiDUYrvPHrHLRAvNnGYCEo/dlC6y@nvmKa2WAfdU7SgD9yoGscagViymOGNf0aUxZFDyIYOKjkY0SWeaPLYiCbONa20Q6TYcqgetAUSAfZGhknUnrovUfV6p@ikU2nLsAdQnFNad2LzJi1loAsC/npdhxpmBOMDbyDmnGj4eAobAH0AjlIUPOFShMORAVwxqNEzXc6wJwUFIz8f@CLUCQTHG/T77gvV108Ig4I9R8Vy7hgfIiWEmdg9bfmTaRk9mYTaI6rjQF88gOR0iJQfoDaMIbaFMATA0hENFRa8Pv/sHvcEA4tnqdh23F6DrF4DsXRoadcosDG4MEdaxdYuyBXAZTJ0HhwTOdMvsEZXT7YsgCcoEpXruTKweo456bkKXG@pAbA0gEF3f4EjuTHzIY4aN9FNOEU2OuVDwkd6BhqUEKG0qtsQe7kArdaGbE85Io4nfLzNpvMuSnvIytVlNba61DMicKIvrCUUZ1ADh5HVyAlvyNsz5YmthqPB83XPMXmx84Q8dW2NSlwndujM27FRyIY5kJul2kqKMlDol1sx6V@6bdi@V3ABcbEDCSbHWrXebZvWkdi14NEmI5hyjwe5qpLqigKSGOsWZMgLmQgZK9oUUmCJ@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@v7Yq8I4YfrDSUcGTFGO3Yt9/8BGZFF898L0HW7uWE4HyLIH/VMJU1C6k445vVYgcpu14WsvdgYMWN9jdRi530wA61LJvgcEk9x3EDjiJRDhpij4UwBAApKholJ9j0jxHhCVowu7mxIWkFLIMAH7riCCAQPOquYzZN4Ws/kanK7nEsGimZEVhFI8t0sGKcKTYvQITtmKfWOhaPfMY@wbggCPvm55BrztiWWhdWJzKpfivILILmPf@AaQthQlZ47Gltk1/Tb3ZQ8eBDwFWwMZD9mmPvJMIoT5RiBMy0BQACYYfji07DtHxOymRCjIN64WEjZc13F5uv7Qdc4ZOSBYLFqpO84IqTt7QQwXctAg1po2ivfBWEpDqb6UhZiNqcQvJ5Pya8e0U5fJtbW1ZDXZgBFzbW0TTBto2kRTGkybZJLIhHAymihEhkzo26QQ6HaSvGqGMU/FE@wOUxzt35rjlN6sVnMnGb2pBm8N3yLUM4wYAC3hC@JJivU6GkVRaJxDQeVOf7H0OzjqHXVdcxxUwmf6mc7tQS3kqBqg4RwXBYMaMi@318mo7gJ3AcJAd5hyk61mtnXSumz10q2rZAZDizW93oFCQXqpkTxwnQmwIWIzX5XUE1Fs5oD56NST2eR6KlWWQIwDSUT8pCymdV7bqaQBo2Gq1UpCpQb10@wOXYpvmtFEcVZVkA9keIDXTiXlyzKk3xFPxHQSworJDIhu9WQSaqaLleBRobEvLVTQwfNv8orZSadj1L1BKsX7xnAKbij0LgY/nLx9i7SLx9GZYZg10TmXNw4AlH07hJXR85rQGnp1@gzp6EIanzp9LhXt4GP3yV7MmFJrfXqwt/u8TskMde8UeAppgLAK8MpQK25PBmpgTXpGbBkMkA0wdec5wbkDTHzQ7TLJYQQmdXkmIsNFl62IDWgNMZ4Ok6zRYhG8IeR3Z6EMFAm5U8jb@JdumCUOvjRPsyT3gGLvHD1ZmCIbnQI/wbqehcy35PICgFVZ5449es1kjCrbJxnNBgYTcAv4y95sLsB2bAlpYSjOOdGE@IQIQJAbclvISZgLMBhx35yCSBzH@ZSA9UeOFbn/HccG4dSQXxA1FBgQcpytMuSl/P8hZ6TkrjfvncDpg3Fs6V2g94vRtQTWggiBAinKch@xdiPi68IByfF3lRFYqa5uY/31TJJTJ6Y3xOoFWQJHAbcPtYpCKk7uUK3tsy5wuQOoaWNq@lxqhR5@hEEe615KRDlpi8sZiGXII2Omwpk7YmCdLkj4BvDK6MunS9iufWa6jo2VLO9C1ECKatgG1yJfVr2ARltb@9qj1fW7LHKosRvOaqRuo7Fer9yuB73Ldixn4LB1AEDUlGWO2Ps2znCClOPrY@hR5luqoK2BA6L@Ig4axmzOtJibyZs6QioEL7@GUYAtL/QcYEWZj/a/2gU2RC1ks5D/0Jala1bISCzXy4iOXTYHCFYBLMQbbMmvjPHwwl1AJ88J5k18mjykjslnsnRgISFXQQ9/S0GjnZy7QD8PvXqhaVnZd0kmwMm7qFy9UPoFboV3Gyhh/JozuoZVsRDpjQafty8SrpayQLdmUwVSf@T4uvKFDCQaHzHkkCWTCZ6SXEsqkoRPgbyY1mBKzzhTkErNY57uGt2lcU8No6ugLw5uLDQsrZ7Qc0XVtOCy6QHF5O@wDmYhr5d/kE4jYafczdLmmYZB/ng4MWJGd@gwoQUiRrRkAgwQQ5CVJah5YABRLpkFC1aEYr4zAbGuZ1jmyPT3ac7eslF2kYl4y0i1At8doDfzCA5NAxhyPuEwH2RwXn0@RtkDDv8cKDnFCiK@zKvUNXrK@jy2p47jglzpMZXmFLRZ1Y8CD8Xxxj3Zn0IEPNQuje9eOM4/O3i02z7cOn5cVyaeq1hmB2hEz2iPQJi1oDusuDBvOEO4C7hj2s7IhBKFUb49tZ47js@ZB1w4uN8Vx4BhHE8etZ/sbz/fev7tIHM0opujiaVjHquJawCzOI4I5tZouk7HAd7CnqyMCZiLg@2DJ2Esn33@ZH@r/Wj38OA4Es3riWXq6lQZnw5WFegzBGGqnOVVf2D1Fld0SExdmEUIiA3KXDUGsimTJHhK6MYTRalMRg9kkXF4lCScBdZxnttlmpqtVHodvVw2ir1uPl/q6/1eL6@p5UK/XNAKWXiUihWDvSNwSTKmNHMDJj4rghNImAZknl6qnA85HBBFu8CxXCzN18z3lsx1CwWjlK/olW6lUtG1Ui@na@WSYRRL/Xw2axTVbL9TVsu5WzMXyQayVnPbiGaAoNfhZAF5AvFLwWuhO/DMA693znqaphW7hX4lp/UK2XyvU8kWyr2OWtI7FSPbz@dUTe11NbUahsUZVaASQ2gw5CptYE1DL0kFTzEWDqbRJqZVxnAZOiA4iRySmHG4jIyCQ@CRR49JsIiMU7OBewHdwyVknKIJ3IvoPsIF5DknS9aZYwBYJkBcR5bdTuhYQcfZCvLC2iqQyoB@LvNfHSiI@VLNXmHk57gGHSnfpaqS@5nf7y84a@R8KuFQZs2dc@TMV6AX136Dwt7wWgo8iy9P8fGV66Xx3fBaCjyLr8DjwxXv5dFd81kGOousSJHhCvnSuK55LAGcxVSimKKr6nO/MvmtWlIP0lrqvTLQLO4Kxc1Xy9uv@WpFO1gsR2zmHeQYOLEnDvDPT0yct@8v9JjYTAJvxYRwGmFxImnuo82XSZh0tnx9R4hGxImBaZ86JDjPTO2srBYwllkUo1PrZsg@iBr0WAC9kambPnz8GnX69FgCgIPu9Zk58qBpz2Doh6FWV57TCydAl@VgcSp3IfmO0Z@AFKR0TBvNd4BJlTJB9jsdcxUo1ARuPgjfS8Cq7PkEJFFNzstqKPbi0gnQbD4Pe7x/QIAdnYS4xfl/tlD5/sT1IVTw/s/f6UEj3GyioX5BsuDM0LaNc8KP/soWC4KihR7LW3c@6lPFkOmuKLs6Lrnq1sywPGpqfUka6u4IRa6guQFB8QGYcAuu8ZzzuZjwvTyRKqNKXlxnYLY5Yt0l0AR7bUmEJ0ZCtuXoPaoGLgqbBgVysbF5MxhTLhRGGB4YeVYltGTlgs23CvjDiT/hT9wdcFczmmO8b@uiAWS2oHdUA1hkvWMatzS6q59Oeo4EnB4VGTNWXAI7Lz1N1kl9Sz/lxjYalxefF9A1BwPgJ4L3KrDzIcg2JJQq5/S6Cy88e@KNpQ40lg8dh2zUFUa3pOBa/LkKxAz2z80Mq2vNtOhxj0afIRehC7B0VNG4pUmKVJp5rZotvXOBovrw47EMEyQGB2hOvZtOZ3M47M3WfqNbkVaHx7GSwlcqy0PzzVS8SpaJVwrfRCXxCWQqc7Ct6o6GhYHLHOmWpPUixpUUPZw6npuWgNK8jdS1dA9Qyw@awziD5qPHbeiOI1MXxC53broF2efZCbcArFpNDshW0Ku7jmV62LWtVRT0@gLcPE3czkaPyJS0uaxie8QzeUNpZlpOF5yuj0u5KxDtHlSOr6LiOnUEc2RnVaV1nXO8V7IWQ@fM4M/lA93bpbm6B8WSLEIJs7t0ROl178JU3A5Ej@X1eLo0X37XWuq@2AfCKY6ogHZPvPZMy/HYET1vq5aBC8H4czlGR2vQ1G2J1oOi5uXBgkyNmRzMsq5oV90aOFaxPFB0eKxs/InbxzEheN@X@s2ol6reTb1C/six1eC9kuyfKu7pXW1HSxMuLtpHjLeMwMtIWLAoubqAIEngTpzlhdvLlimkrHB5eVUDuN3huX4Rvn@DkWVV7YYjy/iC@G1g/zBApQwG3@U8@G@SWv721Hr3I083oi3dVYhI455aBgxk9LzRpEzLqh8ZQs1m70@s@tbEmBhLadVB57WB@9tvkULun6lsUIxEMNuJM0I41zmDehvIj/fKNY7haLuVwOiWCZ38Tk5nKb0bA48@RpH7EAyHaLgZcGBPxguNuyDF2c9vr7nhOOzZTm8hk@jzsRSpfDc/tcDIewbdtwpXXBjEta16LpvNBvxNZP56wXKb0JWbhX1t8udCwuQyT3kOi7MhbsS4PI35VCo0vXnqSTipeT/qpK2aESDgSkWxTdvwL/C5qkmWUduO41gf04RAdHsm8m/AleLCz11NeYM3CnaDsfnch4czJ53@qlkPPiAF0inUHgret2FDdOr1Xs0s4ZI19NLBNevt80CRidy7UoFhniaX@NYJazXjGcyoqHJZLt3aIzk763QMS@evaTF/W3wVOXdrfDOWJeCTaW0L18P4Cth8RTV@jW6NL6CyzB4IOUNjZJD1FulA772eeOFrJdDUwXuJt0zrjavCjU0gFDY@F1bbIqyU79gglvm6OzBQrrFwVTxwXUWcw1n1pZW7P9IHBj9XdRv1nE914NZhLg3OjcsnPap811kXgvGtH7ejAnSmU@PCC99LI3x60YX2nIzunqq71u@7tFHpro4uK0sXE@7gFe2hM7SHxpDvBJrZVnUPwEifn4i7rRCQ/8Gwy4g@RXcpRWvWcizrPjWL9JFTS8fpL83TLp7T6kHQj4r3Qu@AR/C6cwoQxnqqIBr0V/WboTGBIctzfGdsSGRbBWrhZBF/rqKi4eLObzoLdesMAdRI@P5N479TNh3ojj8e06s9tiYePSioRMfrljXlHiVzH6wwfb7tiOOtMXA63aF5V5Y6hu7b5qkSzghx662S7ThSCyaTHqGzbJlQee6FjNhQj/of4Wt/VZMGk0t82JoZlrdxle1MXPcCa8J3HOZZzvmcPizun5hN4/LVBzSsykGwMrjEm7gB3FkX7iC7ZQkkWEhciWDEhCPDLRlZYFjUlTNKC9s7I70jl@OPVXzRtfJTpiLrtx8zJRpse6DJQTMycwvuC/izsBi9dLCyh5OBd5Pc8Qn7HrBY@Fja0lsDPNN8raF5o8IIpNvBa1V9a5aC27fh3YaWmxi3rq4Ubl1eITjVknTHhFcbXtCGk5XTZpY59viTSX1tKcNwcwn5JtTFcrE5aJ@e0edrIWi6i9MbOS4eIgKWQuq6htfFqXSkyJx/4tTHdgZAmSWLzYFD2KVFuLlqvbT5ZyOe9OUzY6Dj9sonJu60tJZgBcR6ffH6rki/NdE981sTxzeWxnd9Afuu6J7qA7P7eKHmw8jCGg324PHXAtqj083KPx@aHp3fCA23zDkhknG0RTxrA7@/TFq7Nl0/Oxh9@7RKhFEK9n4zaZ@Fe8RnBlwwQH99aVrLZuKdMcmNF2S6bRLe9GlmNngvxarlmwBuS/58MhpPvOC1PHXapxOdoh6dkrt3bgJZlN4ANWZD3fKXT2NHZmaB5woGyblxFRf@lWk5A/ZVOcuARYNBG5nyJQi3DcP1oe5Dj7CXIDClfc@FUpz0kFxesDeAE0aOSaZt@rdP8Pi@DjJS@MbC8MEGTyEqT/ApP/zYGKTj5TXy5FYOBsb2i66Fh@I/VhLgZBew8IgOraNxdm4@ivdBMsZOEGE4utjGeVReu3XRp4pDqmNPfAl3@d82phRvHVOqbFouRlCDpb61@/RzMYohtP31Lj7UAEFw4lkXc9PKjQfXEM@0gVlbTYsXoUNp4pFBKg2e00bNO8JsjfH0FJH8R84yiefwAkafe4tMMIBMRo@MLq483pn2M@cpsG4wlI2B6I6eG7hl4BotWR4Qgz1xuroF9dO7M5kjinbJWDEXrvWx0YH2team5bzYsogf6b6@gneiiUOSAGemO3HFtDqG@5pmBCPmVULtYoYeG1MSQ1YjDO@Fkt/tcoYbp@UW@sj1tR1v7Dg2fxIRzsJLfXo7sYHhgR73X3GXcf/ywui3VEhbLO3BGd9uYvT4wb1VxXWNjmPxJxZhBTmwTb65QHdNw1OemPZkSm5MAt5tuZjDt/Fm5RJOc3hD6GznJsjYs929uFmNbxX2rklSwBKf6R4t@S@XaRZ2Et9/V9FQd7sOrp0Fho9cOYscCbuDjs@2SvOtCR1olCkQNL07CfUK3JFVa9QZ0WOlTBJp6edGB4/cdej8qK9PlzGRi0fHAsdrh7dCkoYdv8hShyD1iHcPZNdFtsUaN8f0IIJ@vhRNwuSemUb3rS7eQUtnvYjmkhWdJNqlHWlxExywOZYh@UPcY6n4/iqC8cw8nfTusdYVLqBMRgauWS@u3KxEKscbEkY4y1fpZwTXNYKt27hLELp@aEaqK22tRFmMHv4H258pMDC3i3k8wT@ZSgMgZ3fvC4DMT1w7eN0H7Q4dz@@b04MxqnFy3FX0BYtVgCDw4t0BTeurCgHtaU8sPt8xiOzoGvVIvgNusO@AySIS7huSYZ9JpOJoGi5XunqoR2ZlG17fHKresTv03JutB4KHNPborYy9w/0nB8fy2FNvmTnEDX8T08LVPcpK6AYFJNPqKeoj2qt2O7/56GB798kWS/WAyDj2rb0nOBxDenxmGh@8THBsC9xMNzga7smhUqrgjBuRrPC0BTjq3e4EZ1eg2WVGgKmUnk6LYiwI9dg5ZyPUeIOBPDqqeWqOaywbGjGXQxiVCB4Pq6dYQmcbdablskwUa1zvAxQJ2mVi1FjfDKPe8jxzYEMWwhyQyh5U58G1AXkMWF8/jLfZZInLaTVbVa9YnQlVgZ2c8BzjRYnsTsekb@c5D95M6Cf1RFKSkolky66ybHIGblgg8i0F1xdgIbP4CjI8q1@ui8shRVqz2qxxdSVAilEV0FC3e5bBPrdpqRPK73KlG1yjyzFu4f3lH/cCDUmkCWxkeroFFYJKzpyRMXTON3m6YXWNxzpqWMI4QHq3uL4PaWeLgejod4dcMRI01@d7x@VA3UqgUQ0sh3wCbpYLjjm4CohHR32OGDw3s2OAQcKzUGGhQCaZjGxgAnr@0JPZkUmnQifu/JxHoGfO9l2c6u9l2D7rGbhbkg770sqW5TindAAIc/LLP@ZKZujIb3AUM0yelEtFUsSTvSppdul2nQnkOozkreE6AUgKKxnk9QmuI5NuM3IX8SAsab8BbJdC3S@UDFcAs7N1xKRdlkStaairoWb2U4mt559@0cye1N@zkWL85@8o4mVQccInUqXoCRkWgtSuELGi3gXwnvsmmZCYCjzB2XloM5A6znl7oMY3jmR4JDrEMccZh90G2VhSVzXDxkANRArN1M6hEpgRqf4ihDXOSQkMHbyzka6S6jkPOhhYRYqa97p6IjXhS5vSkc8KkCAq0tHBxJWF0QlhVGiCQRJT9o4R7QM@Vi1kwcYr0kIdOqP6driXPhc946A8MjoT2ud7pslaoU7FSbTrGw0ywTjpoC6r5svWVMtKrWlp9wQ486BSW63pJ1ntS6h1x4VQDxTsebvPHl0m5Eb23TtPv2CCcJWs8TMZQCYSl4f7h7tHx1vHnx9BK1yFpG2Pn8wKaQ1iER22HDoWaQmDekEW@SPoz8w2J4Ooh1IUY9FjcQQa1LUgCQlujJCmhdB3BF8W3jMi/jcBAprWN1lsNjIAFuiEbFhrWPjJGHWdsSBsoK@JsMzE8QM70Kxi8OTLElpKVSWwOlSWBJV1z6piqwu7yd3uU2N3xnJ7tW0uBcEam6XXnPnzIi6tgqt/kHKPdc/7by83j@X2chPMLeUG0JlrGGZva//J5893F4OFgzxR3XqlEJwH5cQZexpns0MFVaSGIQiIS8N1gQkUgFuDwYyryTT8cwOKFRDH7ogHJgyl/AuxOWJCzdRRU@tJwIWkUpQD5G@QEbl@XBV44EgWwzE6Et0lL@KMCOwJs6jDjMtCEHOcNI7KeIXFwFiD6gq73iER8YBeJ70o@5MJexwWDcfoicf73IqhajbqeAz@kVEpNGknbMqC4Uw9YRLT4LYMewAFDmHFGh@jWIJXhJDgeRdm@UVNkZCn3mudVmPoGEZwzBNGaUsfeyEzGGfPHN@osjcTh1RJhMRkxl@QklKdK3alpuXqSklFBYi/wPqG4xbFt793VEfujLNmRN@jODexcaACIK5jNTjs7buoi5ifwuXKDnmVO4FevXCopBkNL9CjNeMSPHZmeibI49QIfeRxLKCUWJqg4Kinl5SIsC3LA56kB8M3cCg@DrXAnMh0NpAfEJRsJsQBJ@UZy5hhQgxhvfpNPWswlJ6jhPaKB04QHMXsReJMbqxJEtTcwLRDpbxV1NJLwnyV@e4Et/41kjeChFmokkka@iMrArhE42TLUD787h9wLZMtH8w/CMzT7DbYfjuw9cH8O6GPqoLtn81sGth@yG0vFWyym6r15vmcaUlYeZoSkPOhcKNgSBhC9cRUoFmTY3N/sX/IvC5qvcUGHenTSFshmQnlFGaOADPOqKERnKcwb8d5PKnmF4AngFyAJMjjIFtD6RnuSQq1rFUVBTOOizQy7cE0pnxfBCldezNBZaPAiSnFQjGvKpBJ6SyMkPTADPBIGI9QFKtAGGNn5rj@qtNlGxsbTPC6umXUizWOIEpCf5kTXs0ymgDYGJcWmgzCQJB5CPBrBMFSCT2tihgUR7OkmkTC1nM4vgFLmCIDgIjobIeaI4DndIKqAmS2jalPbNNFKAUB1badiJbhMCIJIuJxo0rM631yfswLZxYjvVSONoPwAsFItK4KyzC2@ZK1/JZ9EqhGZYB9P12CvzaY/8kSfakcs1Azzk1FnanrajaxNOzhke3gBO0e5JalNEXLKWpRjGCoEEQF@cX@/g6ihB4OFKNrmK@dsbe1s7v/2cHh0Q2FTQSZvA6WZMnGRrolyZnmycyQnOV7sVK395Sjp9t7YVVGczWfIkWI@Z7X69lcltr1nK5I/QU/UXczbfK4kZCavW/ENL8i7dHe8Zuxz32VCOAOP9BzI9WUeHnVPNlotOz4jeTfLVPCG5fXEbnA1PJIBW/yejYxizOF@8eocN@Tw@PiKp4Vx0OEvnM6P3keOEQ8OHgYC1CAmKyEUKuIJ2TggM8AzVWkaFzjv0ekj88SkWrUWY4ikMfhtwGwa801@gWq7Ia6N7TMTgwG8B6qd@SKaEJNKzMVNrI3tkw/JcZoCqSObBAQsVTwhYBpdSrTym6KFPFSXBl2m3a8MD4xBp0A4kseTrwhO3TGkbmtR0Zoeg7cCHs04ct@BvtsMgK4Pr2eG0hiDeBPJAgMFZWcZZVL1dCzAuV40zQqIIT0mqgiLyi4POoVUlNRHhrTnjkAAp4SM9DTP1GBrZod38dCk8I8Owk0jtfwp3iQKlqlH6UjcTqPXG/qsmn3jGkKlf5UT4A/Rffk@YuzpCjcwAFS1LgTqna7prEx7Ii6H/SIubbDa52tMvsswDWVmpUKKk5CTQTQLJDike8@ASOMT6n@SB@z1IRUiXpMZmRNtVJ2xvNdkUkNro3EZuk0SdXwIg/gmhG0TyZCHJbCeciUUofWQVfP7uHrrTlmTVWWT8BMiYgsgTNqOzCU41yUGAMpCYJUKdo6ti2rYo449soc8yAM@sdItxlDfZpLvEkDJk2cO1gXVGrWeBDRCTXvgbxWK5Vq0BqLpKbCAC1uUnlZgWiXkJCQS4X6DQ6WQ62hhnj8lACuKwBZePhNw7YNqCDAmZEOY7A@ASRzxUz4SZDMXKM4pRDnWXwcnFSHjC5qGt9NXlq4@JxQajQ5U7uCMfVVCwfVfjCsXij/oyIrtctUwqpfKMDoiI1UYlhX07n1dDphr6cSNg71Dx7gnM5VAjiJtgwi0hSApIQl1gCfgfOoJ@xaQt9IJXp1bZ1CgBWEtEsI8N5T5MuEfqUkHsBInQEXl3feVMIjZZVZWVavIH/YQxJKBnDmEnX70fdAMPmEmU5jHuREGzPwXmkdpYlmt44Umj6qBdyoMhgF3e0aVZ21xI2vofAKDJyDhgbCriFhDw4ItEPguZ7x3DK/FbwHT/ibeAaL0bZPw4uy/8Kiz/0JS0DvkqRHjKsG5dpCoQKnKahEtGZ0UQRi8utfx9UiE1KJzWLuLJ0sZGvwUGslVmCfJFpaPs7iD0FcV9YFV7hsPSqfMaOvFd9IUlPvy29ODk8PD78UW6lkfOfgpaDmAbTEKnTf9yoxbcXFPu6Kx9eVWFxZVx@UFOXVq1fA7sLVbMiNKJR8Ijal5EkzVQJLo1RazxTL65nnD5NtzIqY0jTxiJmmwlrm2Ov14HaG9FWeVJxfbHMT0wID/FngNpr2uds8MxwkcA3Dhl53wFXbeiHOWiVdX0/ntYd2Tday2i9/sXaVuTxsb/zyuyPFWMPXAb5@cPUUzUdq4ZO1tU@2t/P5DFQeNx9@dfjtra2t/KNM4bBZ2MxL2bWNv/qLtTVN29CUtRPPU0@SzdMvBS2bF@Rf/jx5ePittudh@@GVYyoY8VmGW2WFAjtlb@E67TP8k/ltL2LW0dzpv8UBEpjlOhGbZLKQSx69TGJx38ZVVY1f0K9N1bDG1MZm6b/86OBN3I83NOWFC28//iZeLMe5EQxgy4W2s3gjvoFgxav4hVKv18FY@i//DsI3PoN40OdiAx6NQhhX8SLekOoU5F28UQSDqmmQ7v/zne/E4o0pIkJjf49pDW2d44pafqA@mLVRK66W8wcPQ@vDA62gbSBUeCGBUVWtFbZnpLmxaWfOQyg8tCtzIm6zdg8xI84CbCDDx8DhB5yKaw9fPVKUBgy1eFWrD1vtIN8KK5UFx4HuXAPbE@5YCzynjiQ5EMBJt2oSXkER4uV6ps2Tn@FqPGK4VuDZkwVln9k/Em4Xr7/@v/76x3/9I/r9mO7/FIuHWzOk5lnjpMEvaD6hgfSJBfanNnvKL9uGP9yhFV3QAUw2m5clHm808EH/wEYmel9zC3waMwtBzIPcAhfQDEo3Fn@vKKyKzXPWmF28CAqb2akIPNdkeBop2bxsiAKbcK3Bj/5wzaz4XCOXwJlAbl5rrHHbdSv1jcWb8ebJyXSDRSO5PUK8nsuIbXJgC3E1fhaLS0Aa0unnwDMGyAxXK33X9TncstwObIrMY4zH4v@gVyPG4pdwnaSlq6um/DJdqwV/YKVqMxte3ARZOrmSpI2XjXS6SVlrNoI8bkgnDZlRjinfcvvlBsSb3mhu1J0duuU2Vo6UzDvJovPw5GWjubEYRxDNw4dprM6HEE8jccKAiYcmuNq4alw1N66uNjbgv0HPq@ANrlcbN/70ml@1FUCz6@oEG73VVBotpRW05AnYZaWBLrLSAkMD3gDXbMbil4gurHlC6s3qUlMtFk4kRl1iHeiUUlXXtZxSmH5S3NWgx3sIrgmCso6GdzgyAX9RicWRS69wZr1CDq8@fP1/4N368PW/AStkDb8jR76dN/h78hZ/b3z8HXfx9/wN/o7f4u@5j79DD39PO/iLxeuMAXOU2Mxa2bOseqqegsFkWeBNh9mh2kPqnzVY9iJ7wbIjR@2ByYBfFkxmts@yA5a1s7aqgicYfJb10dSH1wB@fYjFhZ@ZzWLk2TMGqVg4ppBaYHq/azOxFWuy5CsDuBpZlbNy0WyfFIrjN83kSS2utFoKZ/OYlq@RGuirK9Zu7z571G4riPitp87B/H9wMIpab/2PDpynB87Igf/BwcHTFhCsRvphWnoIV72R3ghem/FGbbNVlRB/5QCT48rGZquRk9BcTANWauiW/shrHiO8G2utGEjBL16c1168wP/5We28RoaZlRvaAUAAxg0QijtABC@gZ75ovVBekA2uM4qXbGg8B8/QxA3Ki3NwesGAM5/9oTqi1n@Av/n/r//Tz1mqeSJCH7i82kjRJeJPFC@vLq@CZ0NMpQJLagN@6AB2DHJ51UAjAV2CqZkST8SrK@4Gz5S4wSNsYBobDQo8BwRCEZ@lSenyR@of9o1p86uVBIYIZNZUsODWak2zWbHWAZfZrLv@jtZuxBrtakl0cL0N5DRVJIhCvlZT17lZy2u1Wj6wlMq1WjkwJ1Kpys2rkd1Ui8Wqls@LYq2WDWBBJKuFRojC8PRuDft4LS5iZnnHT2Vx3o@@/5AUqsKDB6ngiyGb4zFI6Gol@@7dzKnd7pluu43uuXfvhLaAG2DqlQLYs@V374DmJEWQ3Z85fOk1JansE61BKVRAKNfyJfBmqqLN0xzqnu77buqtOc4IuOvPE0TS2ZzNOm4r@asffve7rWQdt0SQa17FCDAVVtjYKOYbjWIezMUyFFxI8D02qUG6oopXCUXgxQXZOxkPvNRySSTXqyT6s/gG22xAR/XwYpdXcWo/li@Iqc6FIV6CS@imVirckeWLqXK6EvzqayJrrLPg12w2c@n8emn94QmwNIsXEtTapV5PKkryqn6pV3Fu6KrWDb4LgGdx9AcPchWoyHK21oq124@2jrfa@ElBXPmGgY@hI1HnGK5qjt1kkybyCpWTJhbqRFFayWS19pAaXS0XWDxZCyClJJB6Vq5Q6eOeFzP7eCxvSvFeu9fjY6aWcjCmwpAaG9M2pFKW9XAl12VOv78GjtByrIOL7p5hWeHXFM4d1@qdmz1jLRY/fLK1s3uc0TZghNb2tnYy2tHn23EVrYW5nbxzaH@@u/Xo4HMIcPhkd@to99P9L3Y/PwR3L/b6rW4YujExjPP2ZHL@BhXuG21jDK7zq210TU9//Vof08VqnDCfn3/46fc//PR/@vCzH3742fc//OzHv/r6x9@H@4/h/iF///DfVgr4/NXX/@yPPvzhz8DxP8H9H@H@xa@@/v3v8Jvsfw73X0bc/jy4I3D8ZvHGOl6AD2WtnF5PP4SafJher1QAL8hnIwbJ/favvv7Rz3/19e/8BO5/Edw/uXn/7i@W3z/@3uobw/3oj26H@eG/g/tPeFwh7A//kLvh@wb8H3K43/nJh9/79/z/V8EPjT/78Ht/jo/A8k9/8ld/@eG7/0HTyn/1rz98/4cfvvejD9/77ofv/eDD9/6x9uH3/7WajT7@6MOP//S//tmf/Nc/@1/o/8f0/JP7/D/85J/@zf/5N//33/xZcP8C7n8Ppl/8zX8AZP67P/0p/n/0p3/3H3@K///9X/7dn/6vf/fb/4oMf8AN/@@/@Lf8@bff/f7ffu@f/@13v17x/P6tz6/v4f71fweX@@fzPvHcp1wf6/L1b5Sf/5bamKcCOEAfP2Aa8LjbFwarsViWZYMHdMIf/5MPv/9bgNu/B5Bg@5/BBn9uAa8fkOXLLxf80jTTIaW//BJExC8D0fPLKNAPGHunABueffgOAL4kX36xGRQk@r8hFICxACoEW0icQHAXJXf@1df//OfoPguJrr8VjS8bukZgEwj8LiziD7Azz4oRhf0BkoMPP/3Oh5//4w8//YMPP/1tHBGkfCWzlZHUO@ZRAbBwDzgELN4HDgBVFBNBnl@LaWBYw9mztZiafvUKGmENTCBlrccKObDF1AaZVTRDQJD@1/kMVRon6uCexvIVsIEBnKZkAK80eG2n8UPX6di0Dn4Eil/IZmhslMFpihMJdYgXA/EwmXYZBBg23aZYIGQ9/Zy11@tTHjCNDg2KgWGG0Om5oGpCulx/BAnWp48YxoWRp2Ov4P2q3ijXpw2M7j1lAeJIb0OSAIUf4E5PG@/BXqc4AT42ffQeslKup9ONMrjUqaiUWqZNaaoFKhyVPc2o3OjOGO5k3HzI2CeCWhb4PAdUJQug8ZmeQ2/S/OUm@LfS60Fx6B8a6V7H8NBOU6of7sb9N9GZwgcAEK8k4QY4uCUJc/MQvKc8qjQlC680jwFqLk3cUxglOBCbko6lqX3TZIH0IQ8fc23wARqjw@IkEgkwbTSEnNA@ALkRBDT3tOr5uosLdMQ8VplQrAjojLuJcLNZ4pDEy/VH6/BU4b@7RjuDqSS19VgiifMUSRamJKVzTt6J80KEJSTbOhUgTYDsE/DB@@FDMEMN0XvuhlML9E/HXsZjLE4tD10lw5/wkuvkHulI5PCyHkvP7cHsL4aQ5YycyQRvmd7kIAcGmXyDt5wgLpFxSYcWgZlazDMxlqIPSYnYPl0DWTAWe@oNtp0pSBkZQcioRVzcEYOJmeOqhn01tlvNwvPbTrVaf6/mSzF4k32CH7QKPq0EWIOf9ZY3NrD1G5cSzR6hEfjUYqzRCNa0mRprHO0eA/jxAVO1rMxAQrnMl7R8IV/QcsVioaSp@WIlXyyUc0BTi9mCpqmVfL5SrpSu@CQ9kKVMdb1T2Gj8oxvX//CPll3LXfGKNb5kUxlny6WrWMOq832VCVzbFlpZoUbTWFSPiWY2gz8tl4Mn5DGjFkona2vWpYRFbtFmvkvcPQDZjF1KOP/@DbhY7Bsx9g1wggvSwNU9FuzH2D@oBWvv@E1Kvv4uqAVAYTHWAhTmsUFjXl5eRu5YfO2rr3zWaICgIe3vxeLQ@YYsXGyWzJ48lOlLkr2Ja5DvgLFH@1/sH@0fPJMf7R8B3/9tPOcjx@JXV1f92RIJWQ12cHAQQ6oH0lxOxfBXXTaZTMi3A/arqR4bR6/aOKZpkpaTcqqk5vB/h0HD//3hNfhr@IRQOS3Gz55ZeBwmnBurxN6/fz@lnQzVfdsPtjRo@TK6sxj2gQcwtDxQubFQnBuzaNwINA80YrRy2wSMO4nhZ8qaJ7ENZeZ5jEognkHTAa7b7AluYPYdduzwjbLbRncFxM5Qpw@v7bgOyHW/Ocy2bp9yr0cmP40@83qsozpab2T6wxUQn49HeCrNcP@7xbA76kAGcQ2HA2zDw7UcZxlAiX1@uKKUT2fKY3CTBGmPAfDn@58@Po68j3e3dh7Himz74Nmja69CAFRgT3b3jmfWEvcNgxZmUXx798mT69bgBYS0RqL8GiuUQoPK4rqvg9TfZPmTmn@1qT54oCaUwyc4U3DoQiVajsJY67208YXUKNdcY@q/T9sT9nkFqFpjF1oa4thx69uJPlDmgdGErgZy9AnOFUDBgW2xDDn2FPdfVlR@mMj0YnSmDz/fhZ/q82N4JL2Hn@jGyZwOfit7MmYrHeGFTmh0zcEQxoRzJwSIdXSdwf2xF4SPyvdQObc6@DwNcrvhYy0Bx0V/s8@yMZl6uVYpF8qVnFbOlCvlfEEtFgoZVcuopXKpAhQ5q5bVYrlQUTPlfCWXhyEDfAuVUiwOpNTsKwqMy6ogwLsK0dpd/OLEBn66w5GHjVicT6GxtyldhOad2SdMMCCMgN8@83zaYr5u1gUtj@c/ciqDGHXWZfG9vZ3s3p4gbKMFJ/h3soLQQ0uhnM2WtgXBIJ8dGNY0QXB4GPACMJ9bstntHUGY8AhQf40gDNGyW0SBQRBMtOxs7e1hOq/RomF4ADvlPtxihZYSgNloyeVI4hCEN7PoAG6LJ5SnnO6iBdNEnz3uswN@gvBpmJ9sFmJ4zuF4DI/Dsm5tCcI@t2xtoc9nVPACz@o30bJFlyC4YAEkFIQBGAauYdiC0AEjoqIgdMHUvdDBDb/ugTpNbF8XhAteQVhFgjAlaL17KgBnHLhjMo8fP9aHfs8Y8OvC5e8uZA18zOlkd6/z6aedwaDjXmztfvocfT777LH@@mLidgadIFinDZcDYcDndHRx/YI87rfburXU55vgY1/zaV@0DcxbW38DeQquASYyan8GPp@Bz3TJxWODawSgHby2R/De1jvkE17kQ@9ppyPUEFH9i7GBE4fYZ05toAWZkd51nRrap/W1ZCqZuWgWsyc1cmajlHiZrV2hbz9F349ErlK8vGhO69kTkJZKWnBGJSW0plrBFDJro021Uqiu6Zuqlk9Pq6ic2OknWVJSN1Pqg/W3qWfippbLV4XW5qYkNNWTTU0tV4ull@sTQRCr@NzMlapvU9kksJb4EJulk81SIRKiVErrilYtlcTaFdSED0NNZ@Ib7XYqdW7op6KIecVxHvJPxWQXVESz1k9NM9M6zxS7EGvTulrjp@pZ9kZcPVTrMsGPtPEYBxDddDNbRVKcEtRKWYD0FSUlikiNkH7A@9WLcEVp9ooYFoz8kllV4l94VMtFUcbTDm2n36avXLFXUUhkm2Mv8GgSHUsOdxCSnONVY8fIZeMAoDNUHdXBj8rSMXOQNrkqIsYnU9RSJRZrBIzmIf@@Ti2wfvp4RwbeM7Chghh5D78l7rgyfgPXX/DhyktCp2MYyuTHBu4L7IZuO/zAsLw7BaECD0XULqUX0lU0xBHw0zwNPDNRo9PxePoYNeWYPabXG2DSeyxF6TNdPKdythuNers@MkZj/wLELL4kDaUKgz@bjNg247B4lCk8yNGub0MFZGs2aosz0JqYxqexRg914WzXty8nVWQTr2pGnb6ULsTx@NemXZ/Ynt43Dg0XTx7tH8DwbOARn@7wVWsXAXegsi@vpIbL7Hkh9j1eR7NzJJShS8xQ4NGuZ69q0VyndKnREWuDehNB3@FjQxKEE0lqvjsBoakWa0Dvq13E9bo36fDPCWY7IC8Va1NwU0v52pB16p2X05pbHwObz2oW1GJEemF6jeDfWTCQtuV2fTqvjVy9qYH8ks2EEo2G28oyWraS0VQYSWGEhZBwl8Ceh1uFG/xVlHdSVkpgTMhkp1lZzaiGmgHh8ZXZeyVmfGfXhhbJVqvYMNCoZIW3zsS0tm6leg7TNyRqY@jiNcq4nhmysQmPFIR7bugWBRBFiaWkN5vFdCErirU3kGs3kerJ2@JmvtZLbbO2CA7AG8CtsWK@1q@nXoqLdSzWUmti3TPeUH0iqaDKGK9BcwQynTcZNbNsrahmLqW2dGXpnp9QS1q1OUk0JRVKm3032BC@aggn0DRXIFPHWHQ1CFiPGriFZIEzK3N2Y@42RibSMqAV1YpWC0Bi44BIpYQUfmqa72JNJZMlLZkUkzWcxFgD94DIEUVKAnlMPlA3BWB3hKpQ0UBWjBC3G1ngAlIRxLirWM/0xgxEpfhl7OryaiO66eeb7OJCT0uh9QFjg3QixhRao5fbcbZGJklu0FzTVn1r8Hwr3GC2tROLV2kX2nzLEGsFx34lZe1jNwakNxov@buFm2Ag1RhpR2qyk0De03JQ5l7EDuXzLmO8VvneEGUj3VBaMUGgvs3XFssFkeeUvY/ThwbYzmU/IErVpygyspRe5X22eSK@f2Zal@Wc1CCZMMXi79NQI7SlSXkfh2Hhiio63Lb2zVdaAaredkIHkC99IH4wihQKAk6qGK/Y@KjysvSy/PLp5wefH@yxh9lquVqONETrYSajJtXkBnsIzKv5fBckkHfMKajv7c/4rr54LV4dJ3P5ZC4arB6f1vPhmnFKbTQkdUNjm4ChrAp0qa8Wpey7Bke3BnkUNfD58Fs/yU83ymDXgEGsQk0W0lqjoa5rYnz84et/g2fCLne/2HrCknhC/@//4uda6e//4l/SEmXyqoZuWq4UB0g0qsVS/PJyfHl5BRf3K8RP4jxP@ZIIZr54rsYbSuCsllQx7kncBtktxL13gcqOlJYtg9/OAbcJRajFeCUei5efvnrH2AaIho3eYGBqZFKUhYnpRBWkL/iz9zgV9V5aewVUxfMSCs6rVRA4nD9ZbzQa67TFMtlI49lGrUDrB82r2gmf30BpZN2mn@Gt4894OXNY9zywhzawrm8YrNBQGYgvivLht35f04p//xe/2xLftd@1vwV0tlKpFFUt/uubVzxQ3qRBXgyb77Ot4ilhqcwPDCD5fu3xL8GHhyXpK@DAJ5M6Ho8@JWuZ9ikEQM4AzPh9WWAlquyeJzNjwcD9Fo8KBeaO7hnFfGjzLjzc5I4zf3hS0qsqysD0h5MOHY08di/2/QM6OKIA/pggx5O5YzkdZaTj/AF9VMwDUQogUAf9xFZgtMRzH/TRVeReUQdGm/RjQdF6bQBrY7FSYjXGIOUxnuNuTft9gQ6AG1bvyBjrpAcJ/MNTsvs9BEMtWXS8PDzZvMBZzY41U40bLLnDd/dLdD7dIYbGS4YnGqlqGenOMPC8iYAnrINzUrRxX5DRht/RFsJN@wDRd1BRbghPn9qeB5h9eXseAsuI6l0C/qEeLRFLU/nTYSZwxpg7UD7m1iDRuQMlRLlxmZnR3QFpgLNRhxaklYJmlVEhaFOtnmQ4x1lXqb7pIL2J2oGAjUd1MVQSrFBSi9o3XWDa1HJEkQyxbBQyWo50PcgJAPIGwYPjqP4Mj0E4ndekNynQaYH4J4d@gS4B1LFGGowA8e1AFTA775g@AcAARwAYUhngASNeRZkFVO1MBnhyA/uC7LgDxfS8iVEolfOUIR2Pg4egwOQugGpKoJ9coczh6etZKSr@kFnGmWGRfoMg26gIS@edkvAMN@qg7ktk1YsioQ5U5UJJoRZSlQx3e7S792TrePdRhklqAcHx@FzXmcGmIpXLvdPk37cm3jBAIwzCu6/cKeY5kqe8TPKhkhSDrD@MVns6muEwAvyMGE72jVPJOgVzjRF@s41HzMZ6D2lVhsLYyUBFAJ7N50fQTA@zMnEtxJuwcsOeH48LiNKYVhxR0PN7EErm4hKEwYIFHA7YgPDcAFpJK6AGAurW9gEjUQEKYa6w7Cw9EFZJanAND8KOhR9xTKKyrii1TVLf0VnyGBXIwxBPpG0tSXQBdUgM68lPvGStC8x7yFmws9REvAxKYNp9zEWKV9yxs30Rtl9qEhzuEaBCRGCPxdlpn1/@ZRK4jVl8npXyxcsz3WVv64Ch1ONkTtR3LTpEmUpyvcIQ7K2MPEhwqK7u12YBOk7vQka1iXZvZ2havdTbaBpjYDjNfiqd7tbrOfESknTHQJy8MRBDA0U6sYZu/QU3sJAqnpTSatmQP3ndNs7Zl0@fPIYmf27Qmfnmy5P1hJIBBlesYRH0egqBHh08PdRdz3BFeYzvvZnwlMLPrgSJyNDaI6@ZPaHcZwQsmoK9ECjnwPCD0nvbF8f64Jk@MlJJPclPq2FSJjSKuaHLXEqqmem0CEXUm@bJQh3VhcXGFcTLQZ2ghq7Rr3Wgok9rV179LDUQaz68htEkCpBEXdModh8C1T14XKt1Ez/C/vj46ZN6ckNnGGt9Sa9Ipjsz5ABEIYShY/hbrqtfLKAOUBXCKp8fOCWEgSudFBqLZdlQ9EYSGNeV@XnikJoMWZaTcwTupSaZAOPc@s0mrblzLLgYG3V04EPbp7vHQgbCuhNDREcbh7cLIlpcl0I9TIOjG1IKGgIvjhCmXs8/eEBuXI9Kva5lsyKgZu0KYvMAc1Mz4cetXbl6vZeaVaQ@NpfobdBkTdFt7xx1qQMLnC2UNh0Xhoh6D3jIBx6QkDrqCz8z/YsHHmBbPdQB8YAfZq2v5dfLB@b2t76sHBUfpbqdz1QhI7z2HBsENXcczYCrn8ucLQIa63Y5dlEmUK9qV1fG@qmj5HvZbjlbVks9o1QwytlcuVswcpUOcIndfr7c6VVKeqnQ7SgwuPkURB6Z@JkvgaM/Jtu/X7KrGLMyCP79vgrce69Q6Ve0bC6X75QLvWw@3y@rei5X7GnlTqVzO9c2zw8KXSHdxbHjOgX@ZDVzF7tB24PQ4v8H';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63v+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"r"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]PkPPX)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`    [>.>            .])[-'][(7   >77*,68*,R@'_  7 )(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######:_a5# \7aa*+42@n;.202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'PPQ_ss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>     18&1&         \#184O@        @O252<   111111111   /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
# 36!@`D//> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@" ;   L      ;       xo--o+++o+\;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v>]>>>>>>> >>">r"{\ >>>>>> Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##># ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/ >>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                             
#[#[]]x<  >>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_       #v
#- ! ++R++  +++++++++\+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._     #
##############################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>. _++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<;}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ #>*****[[[828+*+@//:@+*99]]]*****<
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  XX
♈♈  +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉  |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈ |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈  |/0010 | X
♈ |/0011 | 
♈ |/0001 | 
♈ |/$0011| 
♉ +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     x+x   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  *********************************************<>*****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}     @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=""[ 4];t}?1&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rext~+nu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]putsngt=>+le.
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?      -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~+ /.---.>/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8           \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3           \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//             $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*<e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Original DOBELA interpreter is called dobelx64, see [answer 109](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137989).
This answer is for another DOBELA interpreter called dobcon.
Command line: `dobcon polyglot < nul`.

dobelx64/dobcon code is on lines 98-106:

```
^X
 #+=    #
,   #
,, W.=#
 #+           =#
 X^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
```

`X`s designate places for `#`s added to fix SILOS.
2L code above has 3 opening Julia comments to fix Julia.
`#` below the code fixes literate CoffeeScript and Retina.
`W` designates a place where `#` is created because of dot collision in dobcon (but not in dobelx64).

Execution paths of the main dot in dobelx64 (blue) and dobcon (red) ([try it online](https://stasoid.github.io/dobela/?code=%5E%0A%20%23%2B%3D%20%20%20%20%23%0A%2C%20%20%20%23%0A%2C%2C%20%20.%3D%23%0A%20%23%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%23%0A%20%20%5E%3D%0A%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%23%0A%23%20%20%23%20%20%20%23%0A%2C%2C..%2C.%2C%2C%2C%2C..%2C.%2C.%2C%2C..%2C%2C.%2C%2C%2C...%2C%2C.%2C%2C..%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C..%2C%2C%2C.%24)):
[image: main dot path]

I don't know the exact reason why dobelx64 doesn't create `#` at `W`. Probably because reflection from a wall takes more than one tick in dobelx64.

First 109 is enqueued in FIFO, then 254. dobelx64 hits `^` from below (print) right after 109 is enqueued, then 254 is enqueued but not used.
dobcon hits `^` from above (clear FIFO) right after 109 is enqueued, then 254 is enqueued and printed.

Answer (score 3):

## 255. [AlphaBeta](https://esolangs.org/wiki/AlphaBeta), 11888 bytes

```js
"Click 'Run code snippet' for a 'Try it online!' link."; h='https://tio.run/##zb1rc@NaciD4uTn7D/bLEchbBEQCIMCH@BCpklTSLd2uKqlLurduX1LFAkmQRAkEWAAoUaVSRXfPRq977Jj19PQ62u0d3@6e9ay9MxHjndhZ98TY4Qj31wnHfPIPKM@XDceG@x/0ZuYB@BIpqXo8GwsSwHnkeefJk3keiZbh93/96zhe7Mi1L3u2G7DA9APW8axz01PYziV7aFh@Xs/GYgi17fVGA9MJ/HIszjTGHPOCHThtqwNuLHDPTMd6a3rgpzM29NyeZwxY0DcCsFgQij0y7XeDdwFru4OB4XR8gMwydmSAZ3fUPmNGyw88ox1YrgNeOcY@d2xj0OoYDCBMb@iZAUWfZxBF@4zCzPsUGHvqer6JybdN33fRcYOxTXMwDC5rYCkChOFZ7pPtZ58uBC4x9qkBORva5nghL1qGvbBMr7MQQtPYFyf7@4uuOvum7Dps/2b@tCz73PMN21iMP8e2R4F7ECy659l2z3QMpislRV/0LLAdz7gRZIN5ptHpWrapWE6byaxv2kPTY@jCuq4HTRaYdjFTzDS3pyGVNoYtTj0Xoq1GFzO8ng@e7rkJRhNaYmiZHdb13AEzHP8CUtJKmSk8RluaR4c2ZBAQjb32IXTHZL5jDYdmwD2huKZH3pAysy3nLMax78hzO6O25fQAzoR6HY4CKpMfa0OwGhuGOKyggcWpFjgYZOHYHZizbeED8kKu/aHZtrpWm1eOOQ5Mx4fy@gqzoO0uLNtmHdOGANPY22nmu2zkzzi1bKOvtJUYVi6mwgZnNrNYezhk3AuKAVnazxSZOXBfW@wt@Nt9n42HA@ZbA/AO2m63a5rsrTnsQ3A26MQ6bozB1R4ulGxiS5gA45hQut2jb0O9BVidThey1mGtGTjIB@WZSmw4LlSfxxxjwLGhPbyk0kM0kxBd11XQveOavpMM2IXrnbGW2Taw2JiYb/a6xsiGFK0uNgfggeWzgQtvaESHQbYgcIB1gXFjYrGlBcFkouY1h9AxsXldRBdo66iVLzwD8MPzw3YMrAFghxUkfWYavoUUC4L4ptMhzBhOaJkLpZ1tdHZuQceDqhh5FLdveoT6FC/DUkCUxgRXxQvPCgAjsBTb7Mg0PHbimabE8dT028YQsXQ2SUjMxRQCLIhCiLm5mdw73E8CgvIQijEEhPSyJ9/6LGYwpcoSzQrcVUGoxPaePWJXiQaaOc0EJB56oiGx6nvmq42GCfdYa6k97zoGscagVmymusNANeQhZFAOIIOqgUY0yee6MrRnEmabC20w0204VAdaA4gA@yJNJWuPPA@p@7RSjTMotO06PahPKKw3cniTFzLQBIB/HT/NzHMTcYC3kXtBNXzSBwyBP4DOUBY@4FCFwpADXTGs0Shd37VHBAch/QD7I9QKBMUYD7rsC9Y1LBuDgD9GxXPtmT4gJ4YZOR1s@YHlmB2FRdkgquNBXzyH5AyIlBygNwxmaAtlCoChIVwqKnp9@N0/6PR6EM92u@16nRBdvwBkb9PQaFBmYXBjiLCuY9iULYBLY@o8OCRwbthWh6ic4VyGSVAmKNULd2R3GHXUCwu6XN8AYmsCgWgHJkdydxRAHtNsYJxximhxzIWCD4wWNCwlQGlTsWX2cBdaqQ3dnHBGHoyCbpHJwz2W9NWX4lZZ3FprmJA5SZHWE6raqwDCKevkBLbkbZjzxfbcUOEHhu9andjwMui7js7kNhPaVXdoOmJyLo5kOum1kpKClFqUKla1rXQtpyMmNwEXa5BwUqq0q@26VT6tLASfTRKiucBosLuaYlsSkNRQpzhXB8BcKEDJvpBD04yf6zexytFbmXHGill0O@cOcWJdEC9dRBCgQ4pvm@ZQzCiahGQC4ZaWGz2WlXQhjrDAZes0lYwnU7NFpxigpHMFxc56YrlItuxhH/kNqBTHHwLN9RB32wZgj4@DWgAsXZq1CK9pJATKQjTxwkwC1W4BIY3wiLok73IYXkZCGcYw7ULzPdnszHRkIALQlwP/BjW2XeQOKE848gDpcDBRowdNA4F5QbZ5QXhK5DJfpDMHCArG1jJZUW5Z0AmwuwFND3F@pmwAntU5DMTGO8kM7RkYlziqcdZg2mFwTDPYAMiDd8naJtIcID4mH1AwkRH1Px/4XuZ2WUbW8/n5PnajiwWeui1/BUT6rXprT8LCz3YmJDSsC2y2bTi9kdEDeuE6EMRot81hEBIqKIkfAClaHG/IUQ4HT8XvxxIPF9OmQSRij6ZpIJHnrRcOhQZSl5Btl4EnQ9aPywKsY3lAlmAkX0gdAM4XEhdeIchcBl4JK7IQcQCAZObYbI8CoGqAwBd9q90HnMXcOZwu8kFoMXlwmk0dKLvcnSSNmdFqD/SYok6cMBsro5CxRW/GA4MrRlWbc6DGn3W4PWbDHyyJ2J1kEQaCGVdFNRTAvTviHLiOuyRSqMhJtAgy78PbATixY2SKYeCK2C7qrBNOedJE0GZANaDnA/71g2Dol2GcsIL@qKUApqgn3uVBcOggsqiBd2kFLje3bLcFZNmH/qlGKajtUcsaLxSI3CZt@NqPnQMD1vVZFUbuNyPAOjHZ9YFgkvsuAs94CUS4KQr@FACQgBSoKLHrEyneB6JyfOm0RWEOKYU0E7DvChIYMOCkaj5D5m0@m6/BaTGXCDabGUVFKNX32mSQZ3hSjB7BKVuxb8wV7Z55jH1DEODRNWzfhLczsm20jhxO5UTOK0jsKvaNbwBpEyk5azC0rbYVNLkve/Ag5CnYGsh4yDZ1kWeSIMw3QmFaAYICMOHww6GVwD0mZleUoCDfuJ5L2PQ81@PpBn3PvWDkgGCx2UrddQdI3dkLYriQgwax1nJQvA/HUhpKjaUsxGRMJX45mVReu5YjXiXX1taS5WQNRsy1tS0wbaJpC00pMG2RSSYTwiloohBpMqFvnUKg22nyuh7FPJZOsTuMcbR/aw1Fo14uZ0/TRl0L3zq@JahnGDEAWsYXxJOUqlU0SpJQu4CCKq3ufOl3cdQ7bnvWMKyEz4xzg9vDWshSNUDDuR4KBhVkXm6vk0HVA@4ChIF2X/SSjXqmcdq4anRSjetkGkNLFaPagkJBeuJA6XnuCNgQqZ4ry9qpJNWzwHy0qslMcl0UizKIcSCJSJ8UpZTBa1tMmjAaio1GEio1rJ96u@9RfOO0LkmTqoJ8IMMDvLaYVK6KkH5LOpVSSQgrJdMgulWTSaiZNlaCT4XGvjRXQYfPv8krZjeVilH3BqkU7xvDKbih0Dsf/Gj09i3SLh5Ha4Jh9sjgXN4wBFAPnAhWQc8FoTXyanUZ0tG5ND51u1wq2sXH3pP9mDmm1vr0cH/veZWS6Rv@GfAUcg9hVeCVoVa8jgLUwB51zNgyGCAbYGpPc4JzB5h4r91msssITG7zTMwMF222IjagNcR4uky2B/NF8PuQ3925MlAk5E4hb@Nf2lGWOPjSPE2S3AeKvXv8ZG6KbHAG/ARr@zYy37LHCwBWdZ07dug1kTHK7IBkNAcYTMAt4C87k7kAx3VkpIWROOfOJsQnRACC3JDbQk7CmoPBiLvWGETiOM6nhKw/cqzI/e@6DginpvKCqKHAgJDjbJWpLOX/jzgjpbT9ae8ETh@MQ9toA72fj64hsAZECBRIVZf7SJUbES8KByTH31VGYKXahoP117FITh1Zfh@rF2QJHAW8LtQqCqk4uUO1dsDawOX2oKbNsRVwqRV6@DEGeWz4ooRy0jaXMxDLkEfGTEUzd8TAum2Q8E3gldGXT5ewPefc8lwHK1nZg6iBFFWwDRYiX1a9gEbb2wf6o9X1uyxyqLEbztpM3c7Guli5bR96l@Pabs9l6wCAqKkoHLEPHJzhBCknMIbQo6y3VEHbPRdE/XkcNM3JnGkhO5E3DYRUCV55DaMAW17oKcCKMh8ffLUHbIiWz2Qg/5EtQ9ekkDOxLJYRHdtsChCuAtiIN9iSX5nD/qU3h06@G86bBDR5SB2Tz2QZwEJCrsIe/paCznZy7gL9PPLqRKZlZd8jmQAn72bl6rnSz3ErvNtACeMLzugaVcVcpDcafNq@SLga6hzdmkwVyN2BGxjqFwqQaHzEkEOWLSb4anItqcoyPgXyYnqNqR3zXEUqNY15vGe2l8Y9Ns22ir44uLHIsLR6Is8VVdOAy6EHFJO/ozqYhFwsfy@VQsJOuZukzTMNg/xJf2TGzHbfZUIDRIzZkgkwQPRBVpah5oEBRLlkEixcEYoF7gjEuo5pWwMrOKA5e9tB2UUh4q0g1Qp9d4HeTCM4skxgyPmEw3SQwXn16Rjl9Dj8c6DkFCuI@AqvUs/sqOvT2J66rgdypc80mlPQJ1U/CD1U1x92lGAMEfBQezS@@9E4/@zw0V7zaPvkcVUd@Z5qWy2gER2zOQBh1obusOLCvOEM4R7gjuW4AwtKFEX59sx@7roBZx5w4eB@VxwDRnE8edR8crDzfPv5t8PM0YhuDUa2gXksJxYAJnEcE8yt0bTdlgu8hTNaGRMwF4c7h0@iWD77/MnBdvPR3tHhyUw0r0e2ZWhjdXjWW1WgzxCEaUqGV/2h3Zlf0SExdW4WISQ2KHNVGMimTJbhKaMbTxSlMgU9kEXG4VGWcRbYwHluj@laplTqtIxi0Sx02rncRtfodjo5XSvmu8W8ns/AY6NQMtk7Apdlc0wzN2DisyI4gYRpQObppSm5iMMBUbQNHMvl0nxNfG/JXDufNzdyJaPULpVKhr7RyRp6ccM0CxvdXCZjFrRMt1XUitlbMzeTDWStprYBzQBBr8PJAvIE4ifCa6478MwDr3fBOrquF9r5bimrd/KZXKdVyuSLnZa2YbRKZqaby2q61mnrWjkKizOqQCX60GDIVTrAmkZesgaeUiwaTGebmFYZo2XokOAkskhihtEyMgoOoUcOPUbhIjJOzYbueXSPlpBxiiZ0L6D7ABeQp5wsWSeOIWCRAHEdWfFakWMJHScryHNrq0AqQ/q5zH91oDDmKy1zjZFf4Br0TPmuNI3cz4Nud85ZJ@czGYcye@qcJWe@Aj2/9hsW9obXUuBJfDmKj69cL43vhtdS4El8eR4frngvj27BZxnoJLICRYYr5EvjWvBYAjiJaYNiml1Vn/oVyW/VknqY1lLvlYEmcZcobr5a3nzNVyua4WI5YjPvICfAiT1xgX9@YuG8fXeux8QmEngjJkTTCPMTSVMffbpMwuTz5es7wmxEnBhYzplLgvPE1MwoWh5jmUQxOLNvhuyCqEGPOdAbmbrpw8evQatLjyUAOOguzsyRB017hkM/DLWG@pxeOAG6LAfzU7lzybfM7gikILVlOWi@A0wuFQmy22pZq0ChJnDzQfReAlZmz0cgiepKTtEisReXToBm83nYk4NDAmwZJMTNz/@zucoPRl4AocL3f/pOBxrhZhP1jUuSBSeGpmNeEH50V7ZYGBQt9FjeutNRnyqGTHdF2TZwydWwJ4blUVPry3Lf8AYocoXNDQiKD8CEW3CN55zPxUTv5YmUGVXy/DoDc6wBay@BJtiFJRGeGAnZtmt0qBq4KGyZFMjDxubNYI65UDjD8MDIsyqhJSsXbLpVIOiPghF/4u6Au5rRGuJ9WxcNITN5o6WZwCIbLcu8pdE942zUcWXg9KjImLHCEthp6WmyTu7axhk3NtG4vPi8gJ7V6wE/Eb5XgV30QbYhoVS9oNddeOE7I38ot6CxAug4ZKOuMLglBc/mz1UgVrh/bmJYXWuWTY97NPoEuQhdgKWjisYtTfJMpVkL1WwbrUsU1fsfj2WYIDE4QHOq7VQqk8Vhb7L2O7sVaXV4HCspfKm0PDTfTMWrZJl4pfJNVDKfQKYyh9uq7mhYGLisgWHLemfGuJKiR1PHU9MSUJq3kdu24QNqBWFzmOfQfPS4Dd1xZGqD2OVNTbcg@zQ70RaAVavJIdkKe3XbtS0fu7a9ioIuLsBN08TtbPSYmZK2llVsh3gmvy9PTMvpgtsOcCl3BaLdg8rxVVRcp57BHMVdVWlt9wLvlaxF3z03@XP5QPd2aa7uQbFkm1DCai8dUTrtuzAVtwPRY3k9ni3NV9C2l7rP94FoimNWQLsnXvuW7frsmJ63VUvPg2D8uRyjZ2vQMhyZ1oNmzcuDhZkaMiWcZV3Rrobdc@1Csaca8FjZ@COvi2NC@L4v9ZtQL027m3pF/JHraOF7Jdk/U72zu9qOliY8XLSfMd4yAi8jYeGi5OoCgiSBO3GWF24/U6SQisrl5VUN4LX7F8Zl9P4NRpZVtRuNLMNL4reB/cMApSIYAo/z4L9JarnbU@vcjzzdiHbjrkLMNO6ZbcJARs8bTcr0jPaRIbRM5v7EqmuPzJG5lFYdtl6buL/9Fink/pnKhMVIhLOdOCOEc50TqLeh/HivXOMYjrZbCYxhW9DJ7@R0ltK7IfDoQxS5j8BwhIabAXvOaDjXuHNSnPP89prrD6Oe7XbmMok@H0uRinfzU3OMvG/SfatwxYVBXNuqZjOZTMjfzMxfz1luE7qyk7CvLf6cS5hcpilPYXE2xJsxLk9jOpUKTW@d@TJOat6POumrZgQIuFRSHcsxg0t8rmqSZdS25br2xzQhEN2OhfwbcKW48HNXU97gjcLdYGw69@HjzEmru2rWgw9IoXQKtYeC923YMDv1eq9mlnHJGnppb8F6@zzQzETuXanAME@TS3zrhL2a8QxnVDSlqGzc2iM5O@u2TNvgr3Ehd1t8JSV7a3wTliXkk2ltC9fD@ArYdEU1vkC3hpdQWVYHhJy@OTDJeot0YHRej/zotRJo7OK9xFuh9cZV4YYWEAoHn3OrbTOsVOA6IJYFhtczUa6xcVU8dF1FnKNZ9aWVezAweiY/V3Ub9ZxOdeDWYS4NTo3LJz3KfNdZG4LxrR@3owJ0pjPz0o/eSyN8etmG9hwN7p6qW@j3bdqodFdHV9Sliwl38IpO3@07fbPPdwJNbKu6B2BkwE/E3VYIyH@v32ZEn2Z3Kc3WrO3a9n1qFukjp5au212apz08p9WBoB8V76XRAo/wdecUIIz1VEE06K/qN31zBEOW7wbu0JTJtgrUxski/lxFRaPFnd90FurWGQKokej9m8Z/p2zaM9xgOKRXc2iPfHpQUJmO1y1ryn1K5j5YYQV82xHHW7Pnttp9664stUwjcKwzNZoR4tZbJdvhTC1YTH6EzoptQeV5lwpiQ3XW/xhfB6uaNJxc4sPWxLC8jctsd@R5l1gTgesy33YvpvRhfv/EZBqXrz6gYVUOwpXBJd7EDeDOumgH2S1LIOFC4koEIyYcGW7ZzADDoq2cUZrb3jnTO7JZ/ljFFy2UnzI1s377MVOi4bYHmhy0ZmZuwX0Of@YWo5cOVk5/1PNvkjs@Yd8BFgsfS1t6u4dnmhcamjcqjECGE75W1bduq7h9G95NaLmReevqSv7W5RWC02zZcC14NeEFbThaOW1mW0OfP5nc1ZcyDDeXkG9CXS4Xm8P26ZhdvhaCprs4vYHr4SEiYCnktmf6bZxKR4rM@SdOfRy3B5RZttkUOIJdWoSbq9ZLm38y4slfPjN7Bm6vfGLhTkt7CVZArIuL13dF@q2R4VvfGrmBuTS@xQXsu6J7avSs9uO5mo8ii2o03IPHX3Noj043K/@ib/l0fiMy3DLnhEjG0RbxrAn8/jJpbWG6fnIw@vZplRlGKdz7zeQDFu0RnxhwwQD9jaVpLZuJd4ckN16S6bZJeCugmdnwvRSrlm8CuC35i9FgOPLD1/LUaZ/O7BT14Izc/QsLyKL8Bqgx6xt2sHwae2ZmFniucJCcGldx4V9ZtttjXxUzDFg0GLSRKV@CcDswXB8ZAfQIZwkCU9r3XCjFSQ/Z4wV7AzhhZplsOVZw@wRPEBggI0VvLAwfbPAUovoEn8rDj41BPlleI09u5WBgbL9s23go/mMlAU52AQuP6dA6Gifn5mfxPkzG3A0jjEYXx7yYldduXfQp45DqOqNAxl3@t40phVvHlDIbFwszqMHEb@09/VyaxRDa/noXH2qCIDjy7cupaeXGgwXEsxxg1lbT4nnoSJp4ZJJKg@e0UfOOMNtDPD1FJP@Ru0ziObqE0efeIhMMIKPBI7ONK493pv3MfQqsGwxlQyC6g@cmbhlYoCXLA2KwJ27bsKF@Oncmc0zRLhkrpsK1MTRb0L721LScF1sW8SMjMFbwTjRxSBLgxHQnrlh2y/Re04zgjHmVUDufocfmmMSQ1QjDe6EctNuc4cZpubk@sri24w9d1@FPIsIZeGlPbyc2MDzQ4/4r7gruX54b/ZYKafOlPTzn203MDj@4t6q4ntlybf7EIqwgB47FNxcYnmX66hPLGY3JjcnAuy0Xc/g23oyygdMcfh8624UFMvZkdy9uVuNbhf0FSQpY4nPDpyX/5TLN3E7i@@8q6hte28W1s9DwkStnM0fC7qDjk63SfGtCCxplDATNaI8ivQJ3ZNUetAb0WCmTzLT0c7OFR@5adH40MMbLmMj5o2Oh48LhrYikYccvMPEIpB7p7oFsUWSbr3FrSA8i6BdL0SRK7plltt8a0h20dNKLaC5ZNUiiXdqR5jfBAZtjm3LQxz2WahCsIhjPrLNR5x5rXdECymhg4pr1/MrNSqRy/T5hhLt8lX5CcD0z3LqNuwSh60dmpLry9kqUxejhf7jzmQoDc7OQwxP8o7HcA3J2974AyPzIc8LXfdDuyPWDrjU@HKIaJ9dbRV@wWHkIAi/eHdC0vqoQ0J7OyObzHb2ZHV2DDsl3wA12XTDZRMIDUzadc5lUHI2j5UrPiPTIrGzDxc2h2h27Qy/8yXogeMhDn97q0D86eHJ4ogx97ZaZQ9zwN7JsXN2jrERuUEAyrZ6iPqa9arfzm48Od/aebDOxA0TGdaQ7oMMF0WHfaJmBoRpL@k14hIa0/Uz0Qvjp8HAXuFleeIDcVyLVVeFJOCJs0ZkMcDTa7RHOwQByKIwARdFIpSQpFoZ67F6wAerFwUA@Heg8s4YVlomMWJY@jF0Ej0faRZYw2GaV6dkMk6QK1w4BBYfWG5kV1rWiqLd93@o5kIUoB6TYB5V@cJ1BPgMGOYjirddZ4mpczpS1a1ZlQllgp6c8x3hRInvjIWnlec6D1xPGaTWRlOVkItlwyiyTnICbNgiGS8GNOVjILL7CDE/ql2vscknd1qQ2K1ypCRBsVBjUN5yObbLPHVoQhfJ7XDUH1/tyght9f/nHnVCPEukLG1i@YUOFoCo0d2D23Ystnm5UXcOhgXqYMA6Q8W2uFUTe3WYgYAbtPlefBM31@f5JMVTKEupdA8sRn6ab5IJjDq4V4gHTgCMGz83ksGCY8CRUVCiQXEYDB1iFTtD3FXZs0dnRkTc9DRJqo3MCDxcEOml2wDom7qmkI8G0/mW77hkdE8Kc/PKPuSoaOhgcHtiMkicVVDMp4vlfjfS/tNvuCHIdRfLW9NwQRMRKBql@hKvNpAGN3CU8Lks6cgDb5UhDDCXD1cTsbh8zeY8lUbcaanSoWF0xsf380y/qmdPqezZQzf/0HVW6CitO@EQuFXwhzSKQyjUi1qx3HrynvkkmJMYCT3ByatoKZZML3h6oF44jGR6cjnDMdYdRt0Fml5RaTbAxVBYhopnaOVIVMyAFYYSw5gWpiqHjeQ5SX1JQ50MHA6tEUfNeV02II74AKh8HLA8JorodA0xcpRidI0a1JxgkMWbvGFFI4Ha1fAZsvCJt1LQzqO5EO@6zsych1Edma0S7gc91Rc9XqTiJZnWzRiYYTV3UeFV/2RjrGbkx3tg7Bf49rNRGY/xJRv8Sat31INQDFXve3rNHVwmllnn3zjcumSBcJyv85AaQicTV0cHR3vHJ9snnx9AK1xFp2@fntyJag1hERzL7rk26xKBekJH@CPozsU3JIGqrlKTY7OE5Ag3rWpCFBDfOkKa50HcEXxbeN2f8bwKENK1rsdhkZAAsMAjZsNaw8KMhakRjYdhQqxNhmYXjB3agScXg@ZgltJSqSmBVqCwZKuueVcVWF3aLu92nxu6M5fZq21oKgjU2Sa8@8edFXFoF1/8g5R4avv9fX24ey@3lJphbyg2gE9cozP72wZPPn@/NB4sGeaK61VI@PDXKiTP2NM6MR2qsSFlDGBAXkKsCEygAt4aDGVemaQYXJhQrJI7tAQ9MGEr5F2JTxISaqaI@19OQCxFFygHyN8iILB5qBU55JovRGD0T3RUv4oQI7AuTqKOMK0IYc5z0kip4RcXAWMPqirreERHxkF4n/Vn2Jx31OCwajtEjn/e5FUPVZNTxGfxnRqXIpJ@yMQuHM@2UyUyH2zadHhQ4gpUqfIxiCV4RQoLnXZjkF/VJQp46rw1as6HDGuFhUBilbWPoR8xgnD1zA7PM3oxcUjgREZMJf0GqTA2u/pWalis1JUUWICQDgxyNWxTfwf5xFbkzzpoRfZ/FuZGDAxUAcU2s4ZHwwEONxfysLleJyKvcDbXvRUMlzXv4obatCZfgs3PLt0Bqp0boIo9jA6XE0oQFR22@pGqEbds@8CQdGL6BQwlwqAXmRKEThPwYoewwIQ44qUxYxjQTYgjrV29qY4Oh9ALluFc8cILgKGZ/Js7k5posQ831LCdS3VtGXb4k8pdZ4I1wg2AteSNIlIUymeR@MLBnAJfopWyY6off/QOui7IRgPkHoXmc2QHbb4e2Lph/J/LRNLD9s4lNB9sPue2lik12UwHfNJ8TXQorz1wCcj4UbhQMCUOkxJgKNGlybO4vDo6Y30bduNigA2M801ZIZiI5hVkDwIxzamgE5ylM23Eaj1j/AvAEkAuQBHkcZGsoPdM7FVEXW1lVMeO4lKPQTk1zzHdPkGq2NyNUSQqcmFrIF3KaCpmUz6MISVtMDw@O8QglqQyEMXZuDauvWm22ubnJBL9t2Ga1UOEIoiaMl1nh1SSjCYCNcWmhziAMBJmGAL9aGExMGClNwqA4miW1JBK2jsvxDVhCkQwAIqGzE@mXAJ7TDasKkNkxxwGxTZeRFARU23FndBFHEckQEY8bFWcu9snpYTCcf5zppcpsMwgvEIwE8LKwDGPrL1kjaDinoQJVBtj30yX464D5nyzRqsoxC/Xn3FTnKS4q48TSsIfHjovTuPuQWybqqp5VtYI0g6FCGBXkF/v7O4gSejhQjLZpvXaH/vbu3sFnh0fHN9Q6EWRyESzJkrXNVENW0vXTiSE5yfd8pe7sq8dPd/ajqpzN1XQiFSGmO2MXs7kstcWcrkj9BT93dzNt8riRkJa5b8Q0CyPv0w7zm7FPfdUZwF1@7OdGqqJ0dV0/3aw1nPiN5N8tU9UbV9YRucDU8ElRb3Ixm5jFiVr@E1TL7yvRoXINT5TjUcPAPZueTw8dZjw4eBQLUICYokZQq4gnZOCQzwBNFano/LsAPpE@PktEClQnOZqBPIm@IIBda6r3L1R41zf8vm21YjCAd1AJJFdXE@ljmSi6UfyhbQWiFKMpkCqyQUDExPA7AuPyWKH1X5HU9VJcaXabDr0oPikGnQDiSx6N/D47coczc1uPzMj0HLgR9mjEFwdN9tloAHBdej03kcSawJ/IEBgqKjnJKpeqoWeFKvTGKVRTCOnVUZFeWHBl0MmLY0npm@OO1QMCLkpp6OmfaMBWTQ75Y6FJrZ6TBBrHa/hTPG41W6UfpUlxPI3cqBuK5XTMsYiqgcqnwJ@ie/LixXlSEm7gAKlz3I0UwC3odYw6ohGEPWKqE3Ghs5UmHw9YULxZKqF6JdRXAM0CKR4H3hMwwvgkdgfGkIkjUjjqM4WRVWyITtoPPInJNa6zxGGpFEnV8CIP4JoRtEsmQhwm4jykqFahddDVdzr4emsNWV1TlFMwUyISS@CM2i4M5TgXJcVASoIgZYq2im3Lypgjjr0KxzwIg/4x0oDGUOvmEm/Sk0nT6y7WBZWa1R7MaI6a9kBeq6VSOWyNeVJTYoAWN6m8okK0S0hIxKVC/YbHz6HWUI88fnAAVx@ALDz8puk4JlQQ4MzAgDHYGAGSeVI6@nBIeqp3nFKI8yw@Ds@zQ0bn9ZHvJa9sXKJOqBWanKlcw5j6qoGDajccVi/V/15V1MqVmLCrlyowOlJNTPSrWiq7nkolnHUx4eBQ/@ABzulcJ4CTaCogIo0BSE7YUgXwGTiPasKpJIxNMdGp6usUAqwgpF1BgPe@qlwljGs18QBG6jS4eLzzigmfVFpmFEW7hvxhD0moacCZK9QASF8NweQTViqFeVASTczAe7VxnCKa3ThWafqoEnKjam8QdrcFqjppiRvfTOEVGDqHDQ2EXUfCHh4jaEbAU23k2WV@K3gPnvA38aQWo82hpj/L/gvzPvcnLCG9S5K2Ma5AlOsUhQoci1CJaE0bkgTE5Ne/jmsFJoiJrULWPk8l85kKPLTKBsuzTxINPRdn8Ycgr6vrQiBcNR4Vz5nZ1QtvZLludJU3p2dHZ0dHX0rjy4aYjO8evhS0HEBvsBLd9702mL7iYh93xePraiyurmsPNlT11atXwPLiVa8ptRko5VSqy8nTurgBlkFtY2M9XSiup58/TDYZa24wSdR16RhnBiyVNayh3@nA7fbpGz5inF9sawvTAwP8Weg2GHfJON42e73RnnHJ3a34CF/7QRj26VcvXrxAwwu62NvnYfg4jzGMLl5uGvk4ZVnP6L/8xdp1@uqoufnL7w5Ucw1fh/j6wfVTNB9r@U/W1j7Z2cnl0lBx3Hz01dG3t7e3c4/S@aN6fisnZ9Y2/@ov1tZ0fVNX1059XztN1s@@FPRMTlB@@fNk8@joW76PbYdXlmlgxGcRbo3l8@yMvYXrrMvwT@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@Hp02nppuXj5dmCaw1@9IdrYsXnGrmEzgRy81pjtVuu2weGWLwer5@e8r6@WJ5brucK4pwS2pqzQ815LC4D9UqlngOOshC14Wqk7rg@h1tRmqFNVaaxxmPxf/CrFmPxK7hOU/L1dT2Zc5MF96HyMlWphH9g/ioTG17cBDk8vZblzZe1VKpOOa3Xwixvyuy0xgtAT6X5chOiT23WN6vuLt1KE@tLPn1Zq2/OB6bwp7WHD1NYtQ8hglrilIG8Aa1xvXldu65vXl9vbsJ/k57X4Rtcrzdv/Ok1vVbATP1Psf0bdbXWUMM@WTsFuwIoDS6K2kDchjfA1eux@BViDqufkrq2qlzXCvlTmVH/WAfapZa1dT2r5sefFPZ0IAE@guuCoK6j4R2OocAFlWJxlCdKXKwokcOrD1//73g3Pnz9r8EKWcPv4pFv6w3@nrzF35sAfydt/D1/g7@Tt/h7HuDvyMff0xb@YvEqY8DGJbYyduY8o51pZ2CwWAa46H6mr3VwnMqYLHOZuWSZgat1wGTCLwMmK9NlmR7LOBlH08ATDAHLBGjqwqsHvy7E4sHPymQw8sw5g1RsHP1IzTG93zWZ1IjVWfKVCbyXoikZpWA1T/OF4Zt68rQSVxsNlTOkTM9VSK319TVrNveePWo2VcT9xlP3cPo/PBzMWm/9Dw7dp4fuwIX/4eHh0wZQr1rqYUp@CFe1ltoMX1vxWmWrUZYRbyMMjqubW41aVkZzIQVIqaNb6iOvaYzwrq01YiCvv3hxUaGxt3JxXrmokGFi5YZmCBCCcQOEqoRjNrhAuMYLlYbTC7jOKV6yofECPCMTN6gvLhrIVYIMMflDdcxa/wH@1v@//k8/Z2L9VII@cHW9KdIl4U@Srq6vrsNnTRLF0CJuwg8dwI5Brq5raCSgKzDVRelUur7mbvAUpU0eYQ3T2KxR4CkgEIr4JE1Klz/Ef9g3ps2vRhKYJJCuxXBpsNEYZzJSpQUuk/UB4x2tMkkV2n@TaOHKIEiUmkQQ@Vyloq1zs57TK5VcaNkoVirF0JwQxdLNq5bZ0gqFsp7LSVKlkglhQXasREaIwvSNdgX7eCUuYWZ5xxczOENJ37NICmXhwQMx/ALK1nAoPXiglTLv3k2cms2O5TWb6J59905oCrhVp1rKgz1TfPcOaE5Scj3xmcsXiUVZY5/oNUqh5HpQqg3wZpqqT9PsG74RBJ741hqmBdzF6AsS6aDOZFyvkfzVD7/73Uayips3yDWnYQSYCstvbhZytVohB@ZCEQouJPhuILGXKmnSdUIVeHGZkEjGQy@tuCGR63US/Vl8k23VoKP6eLGr6zi1H8vlJbF1aUpX4BK5aaUSd2S5glhMlcJfdU1itXUW/ur1ejaVW99Yf3gK3M3ChRS1cmVUk6qavK5eGWWcxrqutMMPHeDhIuPBg2wJarKYqTRizeaj7ZPtJn4jERfpYeRj6EjkOYYLsEMvWac5x3zptI6lOlXVRjJZrjykVteKeRZPVkJIOQm0nhVLVPy478esLp4zHFO8C/d6fMi0jSwMqjCmxoa0Y2ojwzq46Owxt9tdA0doOtbC/QG@advR5yEuXM/uXFgdcy0WP3qyvbt3ktaBP4nr@9u7af348524htb81E7eWbQ/39t@dPg5BDh6srd9vPfpwRd7nx@Bux97/dYwTcMcmeZFczS6eINfEDCb5hBcp1fTbFu@8fq1MaSLVThlvrj48NPvf/jp//DhZz/88LPvf/jZj3/19Y@/D/cfw/1D/v7hvynl8fmrr//ZH334w5@B43@E@z/A/Ytfff373@E32f8c7r@ccfvz8J6B4zdVHMT327/6@kc//9XXv/MTuP9FeP/k5v27v1h@//h7q28M96M/uh3mh/8W7j/hcUWwP/xD7obvG/B/yOF@5ycffu/f8f9fhT80/uzD7/05PkLLP/3JX/3lh@/@e10v/tW/@vD9H3743o8@fO@7H773gw/f@8f6h9//V1pm9vFHH378p//lz/7kv/zZ/0T/P6bnn9zn/@En//Rv/o@/@b/@5s/C@xdw/zsw/eJv/j2Q@bnOVy/qxdQ6MBrrpRL0wNOJ32bs7/70p/j/0Z/@3X/4Kf7/t3/5d3/6P//db/@vZPgDbvh//sW/4c@//e73//Z7//xvv/v1iuf3b31@fQ/3r/8buNw/n/eJ5z7l@liXr3@j/PzX1MY0FaBs9FkHpgO3u3NpsgqLZVgmfEBn/fE/@fD7vwV94PcAEmz/I9jgzy3g9QOysC@/nPNkKZoGkVNffomeoeT45SzUD8DhnQo8eebhO4D4krz5xSZgkO7/QmAAx0KwCG4@AwSD2z@5@6@@/uc/J49JWHT@rbkoM5HzLHQCwd9FRf0Bdv5paWahf4D048NPv/Ph5//4w0//4MNPfxvHCDlXSm@nZe2OCWAAzN8DDgEL94EDQA0lR5D012I6GNY2cdIypqVevYLcr4EJBK/1WD4LtphWI7OGZgiYAhufyhqn8An/WK7E0AIuY3KFN0uB104Kv@Wdio2r4Eeg@BFwhsZaEececYahCvFiIB4m3SyCTMPGOxQLhKymnrPmenXMA6bQoUYxINrE0Om5oOlCqlh9BAlWx48YxoWRp2Kv4P2qWitWxzWM7j1lAeJI7UCSAIXfGE@Na@/BXqU4AT42fvQeslKsplK1IrhUsZApSi3dpDS1PBWOyp5iVG50Zwy3YW49ZOwTQSsKfAYEqpKF0PhMTaEREMDBv5FaD4tD/8hI9zqGh3YaU/1wN@6/hc4UPgSAeGUZd@/BLcuYm4fgPeZRpShZeKV4DFBzKT7zyyYOxLikYilq3xRZIH3Iw0ddmzV8YnRYnEQiAabNmpAVmocgSoLM5p2V/cDwcHWR@MkyEwolAZ1xKxRtlUsckci5/mgdnhr899ZoXzMVpbIeSyRx7iLJcwZJyamsm3PjvBRREcm2TiVIESD7BHzwfvgQzFBF9J664XQD/VOxl/EYi1PTQ19J8ye8lCq5z/QkcnhZjaWm9nDeGkMoSlpJp8O3Qm9yUEKDQr7hW0kQ48i49ENL2Ewr5JgUE@ljWRI2UNtErozFnvq9HXcMkkdaENJaAZelpHCy5qSsY2eN7ZUz8Py2Wy5X32u5jRi8yT7Cj3aFn48CtMFPlyubm9j8tSuZZpTQCKxrIVarhSvyTIvVjvdOAPzkkGl6RmEgtVzlNvRcPpfXs4VCfkPXcoVSrpAvZoGwFjJ5XddKuVypWNq4ntTWQ6BN6fJ6K79Z@0c3rv/uHy27lrviFat9ycYKzaFfx2p2le8MTeDqvNDICBWa3qK6TNQzafzp2Sw8IZ9pLb9xurZmX8lY7AZtR7zC/Q@Q1diVjHP134CLxb4RY98AJ7ggDVyfZOGOkoPDSrh7AL@9yXcQCFoe8FiKNQCPeWzQoFdXVzN3LL721VcBq9VA/pAP9mNx6IF9Fi2Xy1ZH6Sv0xczOyDPJt8fYo4MvDo4PDp8pjw6OQRz4Np5UUmLx6@vr7mSRh6wmOzw8jCHpAykvq2H46zYbjUbk2wL79diIDWevyjCm67KelbOarGXxf4dBx//94XX46/iEUFk9xs/Y2XigJ5ozK8Xev38/pr0Y5QMnCDdl6LkiurMY9oMHML480LgxX5gaM2jcDDUs1GK09lwHrDuN4efY6qexTXXieYLKLp5B0wG@O@wJbsEOXHbi8q2@O2Z7BcRu36APzO16Loh7vznMjuGcca9HFj91P/F6bKDaXX9gBf0VEJ8PB3j6zvT@m8WwN2hBBnGxhwPswMOzXXcZwAb7/GhFKZ9OlOTgNg/SkgPgzw8@fXwy8z7Z2959HCuwncNnjxZe@RAoz57s7Z9MrBvcNwqan0Tx7b0nTxat4QuIaYUk/DWW34gMGosbgVEV0k2hznKnleB6S3vwQEuoR09wCuHIg2q0XZWxxnt58wu5Vqx45jhwRuzzElC22h60NMSx61V3El2gzj2zDl0NxOtTKDTOIgDvYpvKeBx7intISxo/EGX5MTqXiB8qw48SBjE8fN/Bj5HjNE8Lvwo@GrKVjvBCJzR6Vq8PI8OFGwHEWobB4P7YC8LPCv5QPbc6BDwNcrvhYy8Bx00LVpdlYgr1c71UzBdLWb2YLpaKubxWyOfTmp7WNoobJaDJGa2oFYr5kpYu5krZHAwc4JsvbcTiQEytrqrC6KwJArzLEK3Txm9rbOJHSlylX4vF@eQaeysaEjTwxD5igglhBPzKmx/QNvl1qyroOTzDktUYxGiwNovv7@9m9vcFYQctOPW/mxGEDlryxUxmY0cQTPLZhcFNFwSXhwEvAAu4JZPZ2RWEEY8ANfUIQh8tewWUHATBQsvu9v4@pvMaLTqGB7Az7sMtdmTZADAHLdksiR6C8GYSHcBt84RylNM9tGCa6LPPfXbBTxA@jfKTyUAMzzkcj@FxVNbtbUE44JbtbfT5jAqe51n9Jlq26RIEDyyAhILQA0PPM01HEFpgRFQUhDaY2pcGuOF3TFB7ixMYgnDJKwirSBDGBG20zwRgkEN3TObx48dGP@iYPX5devzdhqyBjzUe7e23Pv201eu1vMvtvU@fo89nnz02Xl@OvFavFQZrNeFyIQz4nA0uFy/I40GzadhLfb4JPs6CT/OyaWLemsYbyFN49TCRQfMz8PkMfMZLLh4bXAMAbeG1M4D3jtEin@giH3qPWy2hgogaXA5NnFHEPnPmAC1ID4y251bQPq6uJcVk@rJeyJxWyJkNROkqU7lG365IX8pE3hJ4wavL@riaOQWxaUMPT9qIQmOs5y0hvTbY0kr58pqxpem51LiMipjdbpIlZW1L1B6svxWfSVt6NlcWGltbslDXTrd0rVgubLxcHwmCVMbnVnaj/FbMJIHFxIdU3zjd2sjPhNjYSBmqXt7YkCrXUBcBDDetUWA2myITL0zjTJIwuzjYQxGopOySSmlVuuI4Pa7yXLFLqTKuahWuQoBlFiMTO6jDZoRfpOMx9iC68VamjMRYFLRSUYAMqKooSUiQkITA@9WLaLlp8poxzBn5pbCyzD9nqRULkoKHNpput0mf9GKvZiGRf469wBNWdLo62ghJEo9fjp0gu41jgMFQT1YLv6BLZ@pB7uR6lxifX9E2SrFYLeQ2j/jHhCqh9dPHuwowoKENteEo@/jhdNdT8IO/wZwP19QSOZ3AaKY8NnF7Yzty2@XnnpW9MUgXeLajciW/kK9nQxwDU83TwKMfFVIFgIeoUS2Q1WFGtQYmo8NESp8Z0gWVs1mrVZvVgTkYBpcgb/H1aihVFPzZaMB2GIfFE1nReZRmdQcqIFNxUDWeidbEOD6O1Tqo@GenunM1KiOveF0xq/RZeCGOp9i2nOrI8Y2ueWR6eIDq4BDGaBNPKrX7rxp7CLgLlX11Ldc85kwLceDzOpoch6EMXWGGQo9mNXNdmc21aMi1llTpVesI@g4fm7IgnMpy/d0pSE@VWA26X@UyblT9UYt/OzHTAsGpUBmDm7aRq/RZq9p6Oa541SHw@qxiQy3OiDDMqBD8OxvG0qbSrI6ntZGt1nUQYjLpSKzRcXdcWs@U0roGgykMshAS7g2w5@DW4AZ/DYUe0RYFxoR0ZpxRtLRmammQIl9ZnVdSOnD3HGiRTLmMDQONSlZ4G0xK6eu22HGZsSlTG0Mfr1DGjXSfDS14iBDuuWnYYQBJZqL8ZquQymckqfIGsu0lxI6yI23lKh1xhzUlcAD@AG6dFXKVblV8Kc1VMhOlirgmVX3zDdUoEguqjuEaNEgo2vmjQT3D1gpa@kpuyte24QcJbUMv10eJuqxBeTPvepvCVzXhFBrnGsTrGJtdKwL@owJuEWHgHMuU55i6DZGXtE1oR62kV0KQ2DAkU6Ig4pe1@XZcMZnc0JNJKVnBCY01cA/JHNGkJFDI5ANtSwCeRygLJR1ExhnydiMLXE4qgDR3HetY/pCBxBS/il1fXW/O7g/6Jru8NFJyZH3AWC@ViDGVlvCVZpytkUlWajTvtF3d7j3froTQ27uxeJk2rk03F7FGeH6Zyerax24cSG3WXvJ3A/fIQLIx0gZVZ6eh3KdnodCdGTsU0L@K8Wrle0fUzVSNqY2YIFD/5ouPxbzE88rex@nLCmz3qhsSpvJTlB2ZaJR5v62fSu@fWfZVMSvXSDgUWfw9S6kKbX9qqu/jMDZcU11HO92@@UrPQ@07buQAkmYAFBCGknxewCkW8xUbHpdebrwsvnz6@eHnh/vsYaZcLBdn51cbD9NpLaklN9lD4GKt53sgjLxjbl5773zGNwPGK/HyMJnNJbNz4arxcTUXrSuLWq0ma5s62wI0ZWUgT12tIGfe1TjO1cijoIPPh9/6SW68WQS7DqxiGWozn9JrNW1dl@LDD1//azzhdrX3xfYTlkR9A3//Fz/XN/7@L/4lrWImryvopmc34gCJRq2wEb@6Gl5dXcPF/fLx0zjPU25DAjNfYNfiNTV01jY0Ke7L3AbZzcf9d6ECElHPFMFv95DbhALUY7wUj8WLT1@9Y2wTxMRap9ezdDKp6vxUdaIMghj82Xucm3ovr70C6uL7CRUn2koIHU2mrNdqtXWcA2fJWgqPaup5moqvX1dOGZ/tQMlk3aGf6a/jz3w5cVj3fbBHNrDiNOimyfI1jYE0o6offuv3db3w93/xuw3pXfNd81tAc0ulUkHT47@@ecVDrVU65Md0@NbhMh58lov8DASS8tc@nbqZnP@kz58D20x6iHz6hq5tOWcQALkEMOOHdYGtKLN7HjaNhYP4Wzz9FJpbhm8WcpHNv/Rx3z5OB@LhT7@sqj0r6I9adNrzxLs8CA7pLIwKSGSBYE/mlu221IGBEwr0NTUfJCuAQOX7I0eFkROPstDXZpGZRbUeTVIMBkXrNAGsicUSpXKMQcpDPJreGHe7Ap1pN@3OsTk0SAEU@EcHfw86CIbqwejEfHRYe47LmpzUpho3WXKXH1iQ6ci9S8yNn4wOaVLVMlIHYuIRGgEPjYdHv@gsgqCgDT8gLkTnEACi66KG4AievjE@DTD55Pg0BJYRNdaEvER1tkQsReVPRZnAaWTuQPmYWsNEpw6UEOXGY1ba8Hqk@s5B5WGQlgjNqqAm1LpWPk1z7rOqUX2TbgALFR4BT48acKgkWKGkD7ZrecDAacUZ3TjEvlHI2XKkqmFOAJA3CJ6FR71veLLDbb0mhVGhmg7EPyXyC9UjoHI5UsoEiO@EOpDZRcsKCACGOgLAkGoPz0zxKkrPoWpr1MPDKNgXFNfrqZbvj8z8RjFHGTLwhHsECgzvHKiuhorZVcocHiiflKIU9Jltnps2qWwIs40awAzeKQnPcEcPKv1Etr0gEepAVc6VFGpBLKW526O9/SfbJ3uP0kzW8giOJwLb7gRWnKlc7p0i/6498vshGmEQ3n2VViHHkVz008mHalIKs/5wttpTsxmOIsDvp@Hs31BMVimYZw7wY3U8YjY0Okir0hTGSYZaD1DdAD9VZ/mYlZFnI95ElRv1/HhcQJTGtOKIgn7QgVAKF50gDBYs5HXABoTnBtBKWgE1EFK3ZgAYiTpdCHOFZeoBgLDKco0rrRB2bfx6ZRL1j81S2yT1HYMlT1BzPoz0RNrWkkQXUC1Gv5r8xE9W2sDIRxwGOxdH0lVYAsvpYi5EXnEn7s5l1H7iKDyvJECFSMAqS5MDTL/8yyQwHZP4fFsMpKtzw2Nvq4Ch1OMUTtT3bDoXKia5QmUI9lZBViQ8J1gNKpMALbdzqaC@SKez27fsjvh2No0hsJ5WV0yl2tVqVrqCJL0hECd/CMTQRPFOqqBbd84NLKRdSFQbDQfyp6w75gX78umTx9Dkz01SA1B/ebqeUNPA6koVLIJRFRHo0eHTI8PzTU9ShvjenwhSIn5vJkxEgdYe@PXMKeU@LWDRVOyFQDl7ZhCW3t@5PDF6z4yBKSaNJD@Ah0lZ0CjWpqFwialipVISFNGoW6dzdVQV5htXkK56VYLqe2a30oKKPqtc@9VzsSdVAnj1Z5PIQxJVXafYAwhU9eGxUOsWfn3@8cnTJ9XkpsEw1uqSXpFMtSbIAYhCCEOaBbY9z7icQx2gKoRVAT9DSwgDVyop1ObLsqkatSTwryvz88QlzR@KoiSnCNwRR@kQ47zqzSateFMsuByaVXTgQ9uneydCGsJ6I1NCRweHt0siWlw9RDVKg6MbUgoaAi@PEaZazT14QG5cNUy1qmcyEqBm5Rpi8wFzxYkY5FWuPaPaEScVaQytJaoodEVXDce/QCXywAdn8htbrgdDRLUDjOQDH0hIFRWln1vB5QMfsK0aqbV4wM/nVtdy68VDa@dbX5aOC4/EduszTUgLr33XAZHNG85mwDMuFM4WAY312hy7KBOoULZtqEPjzFVznUy7mClqGx1zI28WM9liO29mSy3gEtvdXLHVKW0YG/l2S4XBLaAgysDC75sJHP0x2e79kl3FmBX1TKnb1YCF7@RL3ZKeyWZzrWK@k8nlukXNyGYLHb3YKrVu59qm@UHhK6K7OHYsUuBPVjN3sRu0PQwt/b8';c=0;function v(u){return inflate(base64ToByteString(u.split("##")[1])).split('ÿ');}function sl(t){var z=document.createElement('script');z.textContent=t;document.body.appendChild(z);}function p(){if(++c==3){sl(rp.responseText);sl(rf.responseText.replace(/\nvar.*new XMLHttpRequest[^]*$/,''));var a=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(ra.response.items[0].body,"text/html").getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i].textContent=="Try it online!"){g=a[i].href;break;}s=v(g);t=v(h);for(var i=5;i<=22;i++)t[i]=s[i];document.body.innerHTML='<a href="https://tio.run/##'+byteStringToBase64(byteArrayToByteString(deflate(t.join('ÿ'))))+'">Try it online!</a>';}}document.body.innerHTML='Loading...';function d(u,t){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.responseType=t;r.open("GET",u,true);r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200)p();};r.send();return r;}ra=d("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/162057?order=desc&sort=activity&site=codegolf&filter=!4*8OiBQX9S6D(cbJ1","json");rp=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodeca/pako/4d0c80817de75e8038c5e39b999cf48bd97a75cb/dist/pako.min.js","text");rf=d("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/8209ff1167d59f920334b85d044f81a336d28b9b/usr/share/tio.run/frontend.js","text");
```

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@"  /*"t"{\D8v ef26q--[af.q]kPkPPX)xy\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>           .])[-'][(7   m>77*,68*,R@'_  _7 )(22)S   ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1& xxxxxx \#184O@ xxxxxxx @O252<  111111111       /112\   ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    # \aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@";    L      ;     xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>>     MMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡ //:
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  #>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ; 
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **********************************************<>****+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end     e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159" )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
<attache>
Print[194]
Exit[]
</attache>
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngtputs=>+le.xx
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!'(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__( (weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a ))- (-q?6+50));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num ();(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8            \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3            \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//              $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>ass$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*e^e*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

Currently AlphaBeta is disabled in the test driver because original interpreter can work only with programs less than 10000 bytes.
I tested polyglot with [this version](https://github.com/stasoid/AlphaBeta), which does not have this restriction.

---

Obstacles to adding AlphaBeta on line 1: `v`, `P`, `O`.
`v` is fixed with `l` – make `Register2` nonzero. `g` can't be used because of Beatnik. `i` can't be used because of BrainSpace – if there are two
input commands (`1` in `#16` and `i`) it stops working for some reason. I didn't try `h`, `j` and `k`.
`P` is fixed with `k` before it – make `Register2 > Register1`.
`O` is fixed with `xy` – make `Register1 == Register2`.
`"r"`→`"t"` fixes Delimit.
First `+` was moved, because of this Nhohnhehr code needed to be moved right too to prevent 1L_AOI from hitting left pluses in Nhohnhehr code.
*Reminder*: `v` must be in front of `+` because of Re:direction.

Obstacle to adding AlphaBeta on line 2: `R`. Fixed by `m` – make `Register3` nonzero.
`_` before `7` is for Delimit.

Main AlphaBeta code is inside 1L_a on line 2: `xA egguEayiuFtM`. `xA` zeros out `Register1` and `Register2`. `xy` is not used because of Delimit.
255 is obtained like this: `51=100/(1+1)+1, 5=51/10, 255=51*5`.

AlphaBeta doesn't have exit command and relative jumps. It has absolute jumps, but the value of the destination can be obtained only with ±1, ±10 and ±100.
To exit the program we need to jump past the end of the program, so we need program_size/100 `W`s to do that. There is not enough space for so many `W`s
on line 2, so first I jump to the end of 1L_a code on line 3 with `ZWWWWWWWWWzR`, and from there I jump past the end of the program with `WW...WWR`.
Space before `zR` is for x86.
Currently there are enough `W`s for 14000 byte program. When polyglot exceeds that size more `W`s should be added, one `W` for every additional 100 bytes.

Comment: Well I guess now someone has to golf off 1889 bytes so that we can run it in the handler.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Normally I would wait until [pull request](https://github.com/TryItOnline/alphabeta/pull/1) gets merged, but Dennis [has been unavailable recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50925051#50925051), so...

Answer (score 3):

## 261. Haskell with UnicodeSyntax, 12130 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger=='undefined'?257:259</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dmint 22bont:2 6af 8 $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a )where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id` ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+50+z));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();  (!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2qghUAQUS/AAIdPMDvM17u5sckn373gHR6AJQAKoJVKFRBRJoNjtmxhuzGkvhlcezjtForTuSLa@0doS1jvVKDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIgeyRFbJGoys@TmSdPnjz5dbJmeu1f/jKGDzt2O6NWx/WZb3k@a/TtS6uvs90Re2zaXjazKkkYaqffGnQtx/dyUowZjDnWFTt06nYD3JjvXliO/c7qg1@GsV7fbfXNLvPbpg8WG2KxfavzvvveZ3W32zWdhgchVxk7NsGzOahfMLPm@X2z7tuuA15rjL1wOma31jAZhLD6vb7lE/gsAxD1C4oz6bPO2DO371mYfN3yPBcdNxjbtro9f1QEyyaEMPu2@3Tn@edTkbcY@9yEnPU61nAqL0aavbStfmMqhmGwr84ODqZdM@xLzXXYwe38GavsRd8zO@Y0/DW2M/DdQ3/aPct2WpZjsoy@pWemPdfZbt@8FWWD9S2z0bQ7lm47daaxttXpWX2GLqzp9qHKfKuzmd5MV3fGMfU6xt0ce06BLQQPM/stDzzdSwuMFtREz7YarNl3u8x0vCtIydhKj8Mj2K1JcqhDBoHQ2BsPYjcs5jl2r2f53BOKa/XJG1JmHdu5kDj1HffdxqBuOy0IZwFeewOfyuRJdYhWZD1BwzoaWIywwINBFk7drhWtCw@IF3Lt9ay63bTrHDnW0LccD8rr6cyGuruyOx3WsDoQYQy9nmSeywZexKnWMdt6XZcQuZgK6150mM3qvR7jXlAMyNJBepNZXfeNzd6Bf6ftsWGvyzy7C95@3W02LYu9s3ptiM66DanhSgyeem@qZKFt2YIwjgWl2zv@BvDmIzqdJmStwWqRcJAPyjOV2HRcQF@fOWaXU0O9N6LSA5gwRtN1dXRvuJbnxH125fYvWM2qm1hsTMyzWk1z0IEU7SZWB9CB7bGuC1@oRIdBtiCyj7hA2JiYNLMgmExQvVYPGiZWr4vkAnUd1PJV3wT66HuiHn27C9Rh@3GPWaZnI8eCKJ7lNIgyeiEvc6G00UpnlzY0PEDFoE@wPatPpE9wGZYCQJohrSpXfdsHisBS7LBjy@yzs75lqZxOLa9u9pBKo0lCYi6m4GNBdCLM7e146eggDgTKY@hmDwiyv3r2nS8kk@kFtlzNw68gy3mp9HyfXS@fo5nzTCDiXl8xVVb4wLzU@bkFv6FRS7X6NxJAlQArHZZye37K1HqQQc2HDKZMNKJJu8zovU4kYbY9VQeRZsNDNaA2gAmwr5JUsvqg30fuPkaqeQGF7rhOC/AJhe0PHF7l62moAqC/hpdk1qWFNMDryL0iDJ@1gULgH4JGOAvvcAih0OVAUxQYDdL13M6AwkFMz8f2CFiBqAjxsMm@Yk3T7mAU8EdQPNd9ywPixDgDp4E137Udq6GzIBvEdfrQFi8hOROAkgO0hm6Et1CmIDBUhEtFRa@Pv/nbjVYL4OzU626/Icj1KyD2OnWNJmUWOjeGBOs6ZoeyBeGSmDqPDglcmh27QVzOdEYiCcoEpXrlDjoNRg31yoYm1zaB2VrAIOq@xYncHfiQxyTrmhecI9qccqHgXbMGFUsJUNpUbI093oNaqkMzJ5rRugO/ucm0XonFvdQr5VFOebR0bkHmVF1dWU6lWnkgOH2FnMAWX0Q5X@1MdBWeb3qu3ZB6I7/tOhmm1ZlcL7g9y1HiEzDiyXi/Fld15NSKmrcLdb1pOw0lvg20WISE42q@XqiX7VwlPxU9miSAuUIw2Fwtpa7KyGqoUVymuiBc6MDJvtKEKeLnelVEOXrrEWdEzLTbJXeIkeiCdOkigQAf0r2OZfWUtG6oyCYw3Mxyo8eskk7BEAXO2ZVEPBZPRItOEKCkEwXFxnpmu8i2Or02yhuAFMfrAc/tI@3WTaAeDzs1H0S6JKsRXVNPCJyFeOKVFQeuXQNGGtARNUne5DC@hoxSQBg3ocmWbDUiDRmYALRl37vFjTsuSgeUJ@x5gHU4mKjZgqqByLwgO7wgPCVymSzShQMMBaHVLLap1WxoBNjcgKcLmo@UDYKvZngYgMYbSYT3dM0R9mpcNBg3GOzTTNYF9tAfsbqFPAeYj8U7FExkQO3PA7mXuU2W1jLZ7GQbu9XE/H5qR/suMOl3qYUtCQsfbUzIaFgTxOyO6bQGZgv4hetAFLNet3q@YFRQEs8HVjTd35CjJjpP3WtLy4@n06ZOJBCPxmkgk@e1J7pCE7mLENs1kMlQ9ONjAdaw@8CWoCefSh0CXE4lLr/GIBMZeC3PyUIgAQCRWUOrPvCBqwEBX7XtehtoFnPncL7IO6Hp5MEpmjpwdq0ZJo2ZMYoPM5KeCp0wG3NBaFijt@FA54qgihMOVPlRh8WQTa87A7AbZhE6goirnjJ1oL07YHZdx50BFBAZgsUgkz68HkASO0WhGDquQOyixhpKymEVQZ0B14CWD/TX9v2el4N@wvbbg5oOlJI6648O/SMHiSXl90e273JzrePWgC170D5TQQqp@qBmD6cKRG5hHb7xpEsQwJoeK0DP/XYAVKfEmx4wTHLfw8ARL5kYN4HgbxkCUiAdEKU0PWLFB8BUTkdOXZEniFJOMhnbrqyCASOGqPkChbfJbL4Bp@lcYrBoZvQUhkp5/ToZtIhMiuAxOGVLejBRtHvmUXogy/Bqmh3Pgq8z6HTQOnA4l1O4rKCya@nBA2BtCiVnd3sdu277Ve7LHj4UMgVbgjEeik1NlJlUiPNADKZ1YCgQRnQ/PLTuu6ck7CoqFOTBzUTCVr/v9nm6frvvXjFywGBSFKl7bhe5O3tJAhdK0DCstR0c3ou@lLpSc6YIEfapJC/H4/ob13aU6/jS0lI8Fy9Cj7m09AhM22h6hKYEmB6RSSMThtPRRDGSZELfMsVAt0r8phxAHqoVbA5D7O3f2T3FLOdyq5WkWTbEN4NfFfAMPQaE1vADcOJqoYBGVZWLV1BQvdacLP0e9nqn9b7dE0j4wrw0uV1gYZXQABXn9nFgkEfhZTFOuoU@SBcwGKi3lX78vJw@r5xfnzcS5zfxJMZW82ahBoWC9JSu3uq7AxBD1PJaTjMqqlpeBeGjVoin4yuKsqnBMA5GIupnm2rC5NhW4hb0hsr5eRyQKvBTrrf7BG@YzKhqiCrIBwo8IGsrcf16E9KvqRU1EYe4ajwJQ7dCPA6YqSMSPCo0tqUJBB2dfMkRs5dISNS8YVSKv1vdKbjhoHcy@vHg3TvkXRxGLaSwzsDkUl5PBEgdOkFYHT2nBq2BV63JkI9OpPG52@Sjoj18lZ4eSNaQauvzo4PSSYGSaZveBcgUWgvDpkBWBqz0Gzpwg86gYUmzwgDbAFN9nBOcO8DEW/U601xGwbQ6z0Sku6izOdCA15Dg6TKt050sgteG/O5NlIGAkDvFXCS/1IMs8eAz8xQmeQAce@/06cQUWfcC5AlW9zoofGt9XgCwpla4Y4M@4Rgjxw5pjOaAgAm0BfJlI5wLcFxHQ14YDOfcaEJ8QgRCkBtKWyhJ2BNhEHDTHsKQOIbzKUL0R4kVpf8914HBqaW/JG4oM2DkOFtl6TPl/2MuSOl1b9w6QdIHY69j1oHfT4I7l9k5AAQOlErN9lHztwBPDw5oHH9XGUGUqpsO4q9h0zh1YHttRC@MJbAX6DcBqzhIxckdwtohq4OU2wJMW0Pb56NWaOGnGOWJ6SkqjpN2@DgDqQxlZMxUMHNHAqxbhxG@BbIy@vLpElZyLu2@6yCS9RKABlaUxzqYAj4LvUBGOzuHmf35@J0FHDB2y9mI4DYKdRq5dQ9al@N23JbLViAAkqauc8I@dHCGE0Y5vtmDFmW/IwTttFwY6k/SoGWFc6brq@F408SQKQqvv4FegM0u9DjAnDKfHn63BGKIkU2nIf@BLU1PWMgIlOkyomOdjQOIVYAO0g3W5HetXnvUnyAnzxXzJj5NHlLD5DNZJoiQkCvRwt9R1Ggj5y7QzgOvRmCaVfYSjQlw8i46rp4o/YS0wpsNlDA25YyuASomgN6q8HH9IuM6T03wrXCqQGt2Xd9MfaUDi8aXhBKyZjPZS8WX4ilNw7dMXixTZKmGdZlCLjWGPCxZ9Zmwh5ZVT6Evdm4sMMxET@A5BzXn8Dj0gmLyb4CDMOZ0@VuJBDJ2yl2YNs80dPJn7YElWfW2y@RzGGJESyZDB9GGsbIGmAcBEMclYTSxIiT57gCGdQ2rY3dt/5Dm7DsOjl10Yt46ci3huwf8Zgzg2LZAIOcTDuNOBufVx32U0@LhT4CTE1QY4uscpX2rkVoZQ3vmun0YV3rMoDmFTIj6rvBIuV6voftDAMBjlah/94J@/vnRfql6vHP2pJAaeP1Ux64Bj2hY1S4MZjvQHOY8mDecISwB7diO27WhRAHIdxedE9f1ufCACwf3e2IYMYDxdL/69HD3ZOfkG5E56tHt7qBjYh5zy1MBQhinFGYhmLpbc0G2cAZzIYFwcbR79DSA8sWLp4c71f3S8dFZBMybQcc2jWGqd9GaV6AvMAgz9DRH/VGnMbmiQ8PUiVkEwWxwzJVnMDZlmgZvDd14ojgq09EDRWTsHjUNZ4FNnOfus4yR3tpq1MzNTWu9UV9b22iazUZjLWNsZpub2Uw2Da@N9S2LvafgmmYNaeYGTHxWBCeQMA3IPH0MfS2QcGAoWgeJZTQzX6HvgszVs1lrY23L3KpvbW2ZmY3GqpnZ3LCs9Y3mWjptrRvpZm3T2FxdmLlINlC0Gtu6NAMErQ4nC8gTmJ8Cn4nmwDMPst4Va2QymfV6trm1mmlk02uN2lY6u9moGRtmbctKN9dWjYzRqGeMXBAXZ1SBS7ShwlCqdEA0Dbw0AzxVKehMo1VMq4zBMrRgOMuryGJ6wTIyDhyExxp6DMQiMk7NCvcsugdLyDhFI9zX0b2LC8hjSZasoaMIuEkBcR1Z79cCxy10DFeQJ9ZWgVUK/jnLf34kAfnaSN8g8Ctcg46U79owyP3SbzYnnDPkfKFhV9YZO6@SM1@Bnlz7FYW95TUzcAhvjeDxleuZ8G55zQwcwstyeLjiPRvclM@soCGwdQKGK@QzYU15zAgYQtogSNFV9bHfJvnNW1IXac30nhsphL1FsPlqefUNX62oisVypGbeQM5AEnvqgvz81MZ5@@ZEi5HCEfi5JAfTCJMTSWOfzHiZhGmXs9d35Cggzgxs58KlgXNoqqZ1I4tQQhDdi87tmE0YatBrIuitTN324f1Xt9ak14wA2OlOz8yRB017iq4fulozdUIfnACdlYPJqdyJ5GtWcwCjoFTNdtB8RzBta5NCNms1e15QwARuPgi@M4Ll2MkARqIZfU03gmEvLp0Az@bzsGeHRxSwZtIgbnL@n00g3x/0fYglvv/1ew2ohNtV1DZHNBYMDVXHuiL6aM6tMREVLfSaXbvjXp8QQ6a7QNZNXHI1O6FhNmiqfU1rm/0uDrlEdQOB4gsoYQGt8ZzzuZjgOzuRHCMkT64zMMfusvqM0BR2akmEJ0aD7I5rNggNfChsWxSpj5XNq8Ea8kFhROCBnmdeQjNWLth4q4DfHvgD/sbdAXdVo93D36ImKkKms2bNsEBENmu2taDS@@bFoOFqIOlRkTFj6zPCjktPk3Vas2NecGMVjbOLzwvYt1stkCfEd16wqzaMbWhQmrqiz1104TkDr6fVoLJ8aDhko6bQXZBCv8Pf84LYYv9caJiPNbtDr3tUekhcRC4g0hGicUuTFkGaPYXmjlkb4VC9/elUhgmSgAM8p1BPJNKr2O2Fa7/RrUjz42NfSfG3tmbH5pupOEpmDa9SfBOVxieQqcxiW9UdFQsdl901O1qmETHO5ejB1PHYNCMozdto9Y7pAWn5ojqsS6g@ei0id@yZ6jDs6o9NC4h9nJ1gC8C81WTBtkSrrrsd28Om3ZnHQacX4MZp4nY2ekWmpO1ZiG2QzOS1tdA0my@4dR@XcucQ2j24HF9FxXXqCOXo7jyk1d0r/M0VLdrupcXfszu6dzNzdQ@OpXWIJOz6zB6lUb@LUnE7EL1m4/FiZr78emem@2QbCKY4ogO0e9K1Z3dcj53SexFaWn2Ixt@zKTqKQdt0NFoPippnRxOZ6jFdzLLOqVez03I765utlAmvuZU/6DexTxDf@3K/kHsZxt3cK5CPXMcQ37ls/yLVv7ir7mhpoo@L9hHjgh54FgsTi5LzCwgjCdyJM7twB@lNiqmn@Hh5XgX06@0rcxR8f4WeZR52g56lNyJ5G8Q/jLC1CQa/z2XwXyW1tcWpNe7Hnm6B3birEJHKvehY0JHR@1aVskza@MQYRjp9f2bV7AysgTWTVx3V3li4v33BKOT@mUqLYiyL2U6cEcK5zjDUOzF@vFeusQ9H20IGY3ZsaOR3Sjoz@V0PZPQeDrmPwXCMhtsRW86gN1G5E6M452Qx5tq9oGW7jYlMos@ncqTNu@WpCUHes@i3cHDFB4O4tlVYS6fTQr6JzF9PWBYNulbDuG9s/p5ImFzGKY/D4mxIP2KcncZ4KhWq3r7wNJzUvB93ysybEaDAW1spx3Ysf4TveVUyi9vWXLfzKVUITLdho/wGUiku/NxVlbdkI7EbjI3nPjycOak158168A5JjE4BezjwXkQN0anXe1WzhkvW0EpbU9bF80CRidy7UoFuniaX@NaJznzBU8yoGPqmvrGwRXJx1q1ZHZN/hutri@Bt6asL4YUii5CTaW0L18P4Cth4RTU2xbd6I0CW3YBBTtvqWmRdMDowG28GXvCZG2jo4m@Gt07rjfPi9WxgFA6@J1bbIqKU7zowLPPNfsvCcU0HV8WF6zzmHMyqz0TuYddsWfxc1SLuOZ7qwK3DfDQ4Ns6e9MjxXWd1iMa3fiwmBWhMF9bIC74zAT4b1aE@B927p@qm2n2dNird1dD11MzFhDtkRafttp221eY7gULbvOYBFOnzE3GLCgH5b7XrjPhTdJdSFLMdt9O5D2aRP3Ju6brNmXkq4TmtBkT9JLgjswYe4nPnFCD09YQg6vTntZu2NYAuy3N9t2dpZJsXtIOTRfw9j4sGizu/6izUwhkCwEjw/VXh3zk2bZmu3@vRp9rrDDx6UVSNjtfNqsoDSuY@VGH7fNsRp1ur5dbqbfuuLNUs03fsi1QwI8StC0e2vQgWbKbto7PesQF5/ZGO1FCI@p/i53BelYrJJd5thYbZdZxje4N@f4SY8F2XeR33aswfJvdPhNO4fPUBDfNyIFYGZ3iTNIA764IdZAuWQMRC4lwCIyEcBW7NSoPAYsydUZrY3hlpHaur/DVPLpoqP2Uqsn77KVOiYtsDTQ7akZlbcJ@gn4nF6JmdldMetLzb7I5P2DdAxMLXzJreaeGZ5qmK5pUKPZDpiM88fGc6Kdy@Dd8q1NzAWri6kl24vELhjI5mujZ8qvCBOhzMnTbr2D2Pv5nWzMwUGG4vId8ONZo9bBb107CafC0ETXdJel23j4eIQKTQ6n3Lq@NUOnJkLj9x7uO4LeDMWoeNAwdhZxbh9qr1zOoPezzt6@dWy8TtlU9t3GnZmUEVAHV68fouoN8ZmJ79nYHrWzPhTS9g3wXumdmy608mMB8ACzAq9uDxzwTZo9Nt5F@1bY/ObwSGBXNOSGScbJHOqiDvzxqtTU3XhwejF0@rRAQlsfebaYcs2CMeGnDBAP3NmWnNmol3ezRuHJFp0SS87dPMrPjOpKrZmwAWJX816PYGnvjMTp326USnqLsX5O5d2cAWtbfAjVnb7Pizp7EjM7Mgc4lOcmycJ4V/1@64LfbdzTQDEQ06bRTKZxDcLnTXx6YPLcKZQcCU9j0XSnHSQ@vzgr0FmrBWmWY7tr94gsf3TRgjBV8sDO9s8BRi6im@9cefCkE7m42RpwslGOjbR/UOHor/1JEAZ7tAhad0aB2N4bn5KN2LZKw9ATDoXRzrKjpeW7jok8Mu1XUGvoa7/Bf1KesL@5QcG26uR0iDKd8pPXuhRimEtr/eJYdaMBAceJ3R2DR348EU4dkOCGvzefFk6GA0sW@RSoMT2qh5R5ydHp6eIpa/784a8RyPoPe595AJOpBBd9@q48rjnWk/d5@B6AZdWQ@YbvfEwi0DU7xkdkSM9tStmx3AT@POZE4J7Iy@Yjy4NntWDeq3MzbNlsVmAd43fXOO7EQThzQCDE130ordqVn9NzQjGDHPG9ROZuiJNaRhyHyC4a1Q8@t1LnDjtNxEG5le2/F6ruvwNzHhNHyMZ4uZDXQP9Lr/iruO@5cner@Zg7TJ0h5d8u0mVoMf3JtX3L5Vczv8jUWYww4cm28uMPu25aWe2s5gSG5MA9lt9jCHb@NN6xs4zeG1obFd2TDGDnf34mY1vlXYmxpJgUh8aXq05D97TDOxk/j@u4raZr/u4tqZMHziylnkSNgdfDzcKs23JtSgUobA0Mz6INArcEdWO91al15zxySRmj6xanjkrkbnR31zOEuInDw6JhynDm8FLA0b/jpTjmHUo97dkU0P2SYxbvfoRQz9aiaZBMk9t636O1O9g5eGrYjmklMmjWhnNqTJTXAg5nQszW/jHsuU789jGM/ti0HjHmtdwQLKoGvhmvXkys1conK9NlGEO3uVPmS4fUts3cZdgtD0AzNyXW1nLskiePg/2v0iBR1zdX0NT/APhloL2Nnd@wIg84O@Iz73Ibtj1/Ob9vCoh2qc3P48/oLFykIU@PDmgKaVeYWA@nQGHT7f0Yrs6Oo2aHwH0mDTBVOHWLhvaZZzqZGKo2GwXNk3Az0yc@twenOoccfu0CsvXA8ED63n0TfV844Pnx6d6T3PWDBziBv@BnYHV/coK4EbFJBM86eoT2mv2mJ5c/9ot/R0hykNYDKuo94RWiyI9tpmzfLNlDl3nIO@lj9b6Hty9uxpYnxomSl77b7btdSo997paRIywr44nekdjX0A1N10h3OjH5YMQ51Bfi8cWg6cw/LESSBSWhSqt/CS4owauNl9cQ7e0wMNXOJAH/Hn4GgJOJr1@gCnkoDGdUYBFcVMJFRVErGeuFesi@p9MJJH51Iv7F6epQMjVkkbumAKjyfzFbZssu0Cy6TTTFXzXMkF1B8Q4cDKs6YdgN7xPLvlQBaCHJB@ItRdwlUfeQzkfD@AWy6z5ethLp0zbliByTmZVSo8x/hQIqVhj5QLnfDo5WWzUliOa1p8OX7u5Fg6Hga3OjC@nRncnAgLmcWPyHCIX654zCWtYSE281w3C/Q7qPeobTqNjsVERUL5@1zDCFdfc4b7lf/iDxpCHRSpPevantkBhKBGN6Cptnv1iKcboKvXM1GdFMK4auNcNKau7e0wGCf79TbXAgXV9eLgbFPolhHq48ByzGcbw1xwysElTzwn63PC4LkJzzyKhMNYQaFgADboOiDxNPy2p7NTm47ADvrjQy1CqZ7j93Fdo5Fkh6xh4dZQOtlMy3gd172g006Yk7/4A65Rh843i3OnQfKkSSuSIh5jNkiNTb3uDiDXAZB3Vt8VQRREsln3B7hoTorcyF3FU7@k6geoXQsU3VAyXNvN3s4p00osjiriUDFF3m4qyzsnn39VTlcKH1g3Zf3X76XUa4E4@TNta92TkywIkr9Bwop6Z8F77Btn8vJQ5gmGh79tMcS64vWB6u04keH574DGXLcXNBuU2Uk3V0iNQueFgmaq50DjTZf0nBHBWlek8YZOGTrYiZCePQ8aGFhVAs1bXWFZGfB1XO3UZ1lIELUGmWDimtHoODRqb8Eoy0P2nhGjB6HdyKbBxhHZQYVB3cJucHBgNXqgI7Vv1Qa0qfkyo2eyBSrOcrWwXSQTCAUuKu4qvzofZtLa@XCjVIFhiEDq@fnws3Tma8C624dYD1PY8krP96@X9WL6/XvPHDFZvonn@QEUYBPL18eHx6XTs52zF6dQCzcBazvgx9ACXoNURCdL226HVKIBXnA88An8J7SN2SAq3VRVKXoGkIIKXMuavMyNEdY0EfuO6LPie1bE/3YAwdOaNpPCngGowCRiQ6xh4Qc9VOzGRFyhnIqozMb@AxtQiBg85jODlxKqZFYAZGmArHuiis0v7CPudh@M3QllMdoezQyCGAvTK4f@vIgzUXDz91Lunul5f/dycyiLy01hFpQbgoauQZyDncOnL05Kk9GCTp64bmErKw6/cuaMLY2PKQJtXKRzQkTEdfCCzGSKwK2iM@M6QS3/yoJiCeZY7/LIRKGUf1kaEyZgpoBqaStCClEUygHKNyiITJ/NBYE/ksWgj46Au@ZFDJnAgRyCDjKuywJyjNSr6vgExUCoAl1B0zsmJi74ddyLij/JoMVh0bCPHni8zc3pqsJex2PwH@mVAlOmwoZMdGdGhWksA7@O5bSgwEFYNc/7KLbMESEv87zLYX5RLSbkqfHGpKUnOnMizrRCL90xe14gDMbYc9e3cuztwCW9GQEzCeUL0shqci22VLVcNyvp4wDBF@T8oN8ieIcHpwWUzrhoRvw9SnMDBzsqCMQVyoqT7X4fFS/zI8dcsyNHuSuUCAZdJU3feEJpWCgleOzS9uxah9NXE2WcDnBKLI0oOColJo0pbKfjgUzSgO4bJBQfu1oQTnQ6CMlPQ2oOk2NAk3ooMiaZLGFYr3BbqRx0pVc4HnjNIy9TOILsRWDGt5c0DTDXsp1AA3EOVRLTzEWO@f0B7nMsxm9FCbKQI5PW9rudSMAZ6jXPrdTH3/xtrlLz3Afzj4R5mN4F268LWxPMvxH4GAbY/lloy4Dtx9z2KoVVdluP4DifoUqIuUdHgTgfy7cKhowh0MVMBQqrHKv7q8Nj5tVRxS9WaBcGV@O6QjYTjFOY3QXKuKSKxuA8hXE9juEo5a@AToC4gEhQxkGxhtKz@hUFVcrlUinMOK5I6bTh1BryTSCkYe7tADWrgiSWWs@urxkpyKR2GQAkpTctPP/GAapqDhijdGn3Cq9rdba9vc1kr252rMJ6nhNIatl8tSq/DjO6DGElPlooM4gDUcYxwK8ooinLZsJQMSr2ZnEjjoyt4XJ6A5FQIQMEUdHZCdRkgMzpClQBMTvW0CexaRSMgoBrO25EpXIASANAHDbq/5xuk@MzbTiNGmmlerQa5JcYjOYRcvIsii2/Yuf@uVMRemAZUN/PZ9CvA@Z/MkM5LKcsVAN0WyupMq1TFEvDHp86Ls5GH0BumZJJZVZTxroaoVBZgIL8Ynt/DyChhQPHqFv2G7fn7eyVDr84Oj69pZ2KQsang8VZvLidONf0ZLkSGuJhvieRunuQOn22exCgMpqr8Xwwhhhv8J3O5qzUpnM6J/WX/Pjg7bTJ41ZCRvq@gGkySTugjfK3oY99U5GAe/z00q1UFfX6plzZLp47sVvJv5@lcTimryBxgencI33D8elsYhbD2wXO8HYBTw/Oxht4MB5PTPruxfiYvXCIePDgARTgAJKeCkLNY56QgSM@AzTWB5Ph1xt4xPr4LBHpgQ1zFAl5FlyEgE1rrL5Q6O1rm167Y9ck6MAbqMuSa90J1MqE@np0r9exfUWVaAqkgGIQMDFFXIcwzA11WsZWSOswwUqyRaoAA3iqBI0A4MWPB16bHbu9yNzWvhWYTkAaYfsDvsZpsS8GXQjXpM@JhSzWAvlEg8iAqHiYVT6qhpYlNAEOE6htEdIroz5AUXC928gqQ1VvW8OG3QIGrqhJaOmfGSBWhboKsNCkHdCJA4/jGP4cT41FUfpJCiGHY@Bm2dRtp2ENFdRwlKuAfIru8auXl3FVvkUDpJVyL9BjN6WeMmiIpi9axFi141Rj2wrvQJjSH7q1hVqiUO0CVAukeOr3n4IR@iel2TV7TBmQ3lSP6YysyrniJD2/rzKtyFWvOCyRoFE1fMgDpGYM2iQTEQ5TcB5SSRWgdtDVcxr4eWf3WNnQ9QqYKRGVLeOM2h505TgXpUowSoIoOQJbwLplOcwRp16dUx7EQX@JFLkxVB46w5vUfdI0rYu4oFKz4sOIAqxxC@RY3drKidqYZDVbDMjiNpfXUwB2BgsJpFTArzhFD1hDdfh4bwIuogBbePyl5TgWIAhopmtCH2wOgMj6ajK4/yQ5Vp9OKcR4Fp@IY/mQ0Um16qX4dQdX2pdTeZqcyd9An/r6HDvVpuhWR6n/MaWn8tfKcqcwSoGgoxaV5XbBSKyuJBLLzoqy7GBX//AhzuncLIMkUdVhiDSEQNpyR80DPYPkUVh28svmtrLcKGRWKAZYYZB2DRE@eCn9etm8SS0/hJ46CS593niVZY80c6Z13biB/GELWU4lgWauUZEhXX6CyS/biQTmQV@uYgY@pM5PE8Szz09TNH2UF9JoqtUVzW2Kq4Y1cevqF45A4SwqGhh7Bhm7OA1RDQKPlaqvzvKbI3vwhL/EA2eM9rhaXlT8lyd97s9YBL@Lk9I0rgeVq0YFBA4VQCJak6aqAjP55S9jxjqTleVH66udy0Q8m87Dy8hvsCz7bPk8sxZjscem6cOQPbVyfb6/2bpkVjOz/lbTynZTf1s5vjg@/no4Us@VeGzv6JVsrEHQDbZFv/s@Gywz52Gf9sRiKykplloxHm6kUq9fvwaRF59yUS8GQfSKWtbilbKyIRy6xY2NleT65kry5HG8CnmB4qpKJqOeMttOsXO75zUa8HPbdBWREuMPe/QI0wMD/DPh1h02yTjcsVqtQckccXc7NsDPgS/iPvvuy5cv0fCSHvbuRMSPcYgCXCxXNbMxymQmnfmLP1m6SV4fV7f/4vvdlLWEnyP8/OjmGZpPjexnS0uf7e6urSUBcdx8/N3jb3Z2dtb2k9njcvbRmpZe2v7zP1taymS2M6mliucZlXj54ms5k16T9b/4vXj1@Pg7nod1h88qM8CI7034GSybZRfsHTwXTYb/ZH7XiJhNNNea77CDBGG5QMwmHs@uxk9fxbF@3sUMw4iN6K9KRVtiRvHRxn/7ydHbmB8rZlIv@/D1Y29j65sxbgQD2FYD22WsGNvGYOs3sVGqUCiAceO//XuIX/wC4KDPaBtexWwAa30UK2oFivI@VlwHg5HJQLr/z/e@J8WKQ8hEsXh4wDLFzIogE2PzofGQTI7fBgHjPGZsrh09JqttPT7KZDPbaHYsvMKlDcNRZDKGkTlnovIMUYVYXAPf3IG1wYx16sZYEHRc5yygKCYoAQiEaISbhQORDXdA74lwL89Nc2UjsZZ57ORfRp4Jyz/Ec4J3Za0vPX69n0ptF6GnxyeXe3xeFc0sxTY2Zdd9jJN/efZUuObxNXQ1zYXg8DsnRw0fgcDYZiFZ5UgKWlngw8Y2FnWKCVyysEH9CuFK@Pzl//WXP/3Ln9DfT@n3n6VYsBNGK19WisEDFCQX@/L1ubA6z9gz/jgO/MMvsKILOoDJEXOTsfApFvFF/8JGJvpOuQmfYmihEOMoc8OxgGNRulLsQyrFclhLl8VitDzwpEIrFYPnnAzPIqUbl0@UB1jjo0dL8Ef/8IRWfC@Ri3CmILefJVZc8CzuA6RYOVauVHizni7RgudER6rTha0a7VUupZgGjCqROAEqZYK44TlP3PG8gJ@uV4UtpY@hxqTY3/tTlFjsGp5KQru5KcfX3Pi6@1h/lcjnxT/IefnQhg83QQ4rN5q2/aqYSJQpp@WiyPK2xipFXgB669VX2wA@sV3eLrh79NOriC@t8qpY3p6MTPErxcePE4jaxwCguFxhMLSA2rjZvinelLdvbra34X@b3jfiC64327f@6TN@5oQZ@1ew/s/LqeJ5SrTKYgXsOhA1uOipc6Ru@EK4clmKXSPlsHKFFMwVtLKxnq1ojFrICnCvVM5YyaymssPP1ksZYAIeBs/IcmoFDe@xuwSBZ0uK4dBhi48gtsjh9cdv/w/8nX/89t@CFbKGN/mRb@0t/j19h39vffw7q@PfyVv8O3uHfyc@/h17@Peshn9SrMAYSGzLj9Kd9GXauDAuwGCzNAjM7XTbaEBnw9IWS4/SI5buukYDTBb8pcFkp5ss3WJpJ@0YBniCwWdpH01N@LTgrwlQ@vBnp9MIPH3JIJUOdmGkmJm@76tMPZfKLP7aAjFLN/S0vm5XK9n13ttyvJKPpc7PU1z2ZJm1PCnivrlhrFotPd@vVlNI/OfP3KPx/9FRN2pd@N89cp8duV0X/o@Ojp6dAwMrJh4ntMfwFIqJbfF5FCvmH53nNCTcgIRjqe1H58VVDc3rCaDKDLolPvEZQ4RvcelcgrH5y5dXeepn81eX@as8GUIrN1RFABGMGyBWXvTP4ALxzl@mqEe9gueS4JINjVfgGZi4IfXy6hwlSBgvhP@Ajqj17@Hf/v/X/7MXTClXVGgE1zfbCj0q/qnq9c31jXgXVUURFmUb/tAB7Bjl@qaIRgp0DaayolbUmxvuBm9F3eYAi5jGdpEijwMCp4iFaVK6/KX8/X4xbf6cx0FMgpG0IpYBz8@H6bSar4FLuBZgvqcVJTVPe22Wa7gKCKNHQ6UQ2bV83ljh5sxaJp9fE5aNzXx@U5iXFWXr9lNMPzLW13OZtTVVzefTIiyME/OBEUBYnlnPYyPPx1TMLG/5ShpnI@kKjrickx8@VMSlLY96PfXhQ2Mr/f596FStNux@tYruq@/fy1UZt@UUtrJgT2@@fw9MJ666feW5yxeEFc1gn2WKlMKW24dSbYA3M1KZcZpt0zN9v6@8s3tJGTdeerJKarPTabd/Hv/Fj7///fN4ATdqkOuagQAwFZbd3l5fKxbX18C8vgkFl5f5zh@lldgy1JvllMyLy@TleEx4GZsbKrnexNGfxbbZoyI0VA8fdn0To/pja1lVqY0s9RpcAjdja4s7srV1ZTOxJf4KSyorrjDxVy6XVxNrKxsrjysg3tx@kKnmr81CPJWK3xSuzRzOWt3k6@J6BjwSZT58uLoFyNxM58@lanV/52ynijc74po89H4MHYlDS7je2uvHyzTFmN2qlLFglfN4PJd/TNVubGZZLJ4X4bQ4cHu2uUXlj3meZDfxbOSQoE79VmI9ZmysQrcKvarUo@1RG2nWwBXmPnObzSVwhLpjNdwM4FmdTnClxZXb7zSu7Ia1JMWOn@7slc6SGZBQYpmDnb1k5vTFbsxAa3ZsR28WW0WHk9LO/tELiHH8tLRzWvr88KvSi2Nw96Q370zLMq2BZV1VB4Ort3jtgVW1euA6fqpW3fbMN2/MHj0wSuHM@erjz3/48ef/08ff/fHH3/3hx9/96S@@/ekP4fcH8Psx//74321l8f2Lb//Z73/8nd8Fx/8Mv/8Evz/5xbe/9T3@I/ufwu@/RNz@VPwi4fhPAli//otvf/J7v/j2N34Gv38pfj@7/fvNP5n9@@kP5v8w3k9@f3GYH/97@P0hhxWE/fHvcDf83gr/Ozzcb/zs47/4D/z/z8UfGn/347/4U3wJyz/92Z//l4/f/4@ZzOaf/5uPP/zxxx/85OMPvv/xBz/6@IN/nPn4W//GSEdfv//xp3/03//4D//7H/8v9P8H9P7D@/x//Nk//av/86/@77/6Y/H7E/j9BzD9yV/9RyDVv/mjn@P/T/7ob/7Tz/H/f/9Xf/NH/@vf/Pq/JsNvc8P/@y//HX//9fd/@Nc/@Od//f1v57x/uPD97T3cv/0HcLl/Pu8D5z7l@lSXb3@l/PxdsDFOBWiA7pdgGRBid0cWTVd8NsxJn7FYcQUf4MnlzcxmYgXkz5WtLWDMFXLfxiBMgnb603/y8bd@Dcj/XwAwsP3PYIN/bgGvH5GFff31hCdL0BSIlvj6a/QUY8avo6F@BA7vUyCNpx@/hxBfkzd/WBgM0v3fKBiEYyJYEG4yAxQG93hy9198@89/jzzCuOj8axMg04FzNPQyBn8fFPVH2O7HpYmG/hGyjo8//97H3/vHH3/@2x9//uvYN2hrW8mdJHTti2d5IWD2HuEw4Pp9wkFAA8eMMMZfkjJgWNrGmUnJSLx@DblfAhMMuVak7CrYJKNIZgPNEDEBNgIyHCbwDf/S2hZDC7gMyRW@LAFeuwm8dzwhDQvgR0HxwnKGxuImOA1xbqEAcDESj5OsbsJghg13CQrELCROWHWlMOQRE@hQJAhINhI6nchGRk5sFvYhwcJwnyEsBJ6QXsP3daG4WRgWEdwHygLASOxCkhAK70NPDIsfwF4gmBBeGu5/gKxsFhKJ4ia4FLCQCUotWaU0jSwVjsqeYFRudGcM91o@egxNRjY2ZT73AahkIjS@E@PQGBCCg/95YkUUh/4DI/1WMD7U05Dww924/yN0pvgiAMDVNNyiBz9Nw9w8Bu8hB5WgZOGT4BAAcwmSogKQ4EACS0JKUP0myALpQx4@7dlGVoHgsDjLy8tg2i7Kq3L1CMaQMFjrX@Q83@zjEiIJkjkmr2/J6Iz7nfhOzuVjGmyu7K/A24D/0hLtXqay5Fek5ThOW8R51iAtLbHqrrkxXoygjGRboSIkKCD7DHzw9/gxmAFH9B274UwD/SekVzGJxajuobEk@Rs@eoHcI02JHF4VpMTYTtPZPIauJ/VkUnx1@pKDLgw6@YqvvkwSI@PjHlqoZsb6GlMlhW72UrGG6hZJY9Izr7XrDmHMkZTlpLGOi0@qmKc5y2WwtUqlXBre37i5XOGDsbYhwZfsA7xhTNx1BXSD96zr29tY/8VrjSaT0Agy67pULIp1d2ZIxdPSGQQ/O2JGJq0zGK9cr21k1rJr2czq@np2I2OsrW@trWc3V4GzrqezmYyxtba2tbm1cRNi6zEwp2RupZbdLv6jW8//8I9mPbNd8ZGKX7OhThPoN1KxU@D7P5dxDV4@T8t5mtkiXC6X00n8y6yuwhvymTSyG5Wlpc61hsU@p02H17jLAbIqXWvY8T2Ah0kPJPYAnOCBNHAVkol9I4dHebFHAC8K5fsEZCMLhAz1cA6UzMFBjV5fX0d@Umzpu9/1WbEI4w7t8ECKQRtss2BVXLMbelun@z0bg75Fvi3G9g@/Ojw9PHqu7x@ewkDgG5ZZTetS7Obmphmu5ZDVYkdHRxIyPxjgrRoY/6bOBoMB@dbAfjM0pV70yeNLymS0zKq2amjGKv7fYcjg//3DZ@A/g2@ItZqR@KHADh7dCabMtqRtruKiGFzcrtfcxki38R4aPGpW8Ec9i@7SoANzZ1yTfKEQD29GjT/KZDeA8re2hXap4rbnjzpWEQFdN2yv1zFHOQfG0ze4QzRnNiEX13W@syInZ7Kb8s3jrtWwTQbxcSiGo2Sli1c24P7hXPo8rV7PjLqelm9uIFlKTtoW6imKtOBdhkZQwZvsypXtQHFFUfrw4cOQ9pjkDh1fbDbJrG2iO5Ow5T@ELvWhwY3Z9bExjcYzVDLyHKgQmq7DnuKecd9lZy7fm7xr1eeE2GubdLHfXt@FIeuvHmbXdC64177NtR2EXk9MVHfsdW2/PSfEi14XTz1a/X8wCKVuDTKIRMQD7MKr33HdWQE22IvjOaV8Fionwn0ppJ0Igp8cfv7kLPI9K@3sPZHW2e7R8/2pT1YEyrKnpYOz0LrBfYOo2RDEN6WnT6et4gP9Qp7mKJZYdiMwGCxm@mZBTlblMlur5P2bR8b2w4fGcur4Kc6CHPcBjx03xdj5B237K624me9bQ98ZsBdbwKWLJahqALLXL@wuN6GnaVll4BoHO3sVKLWOMyEdS68WG11qo5ka0Hsuw9bNJttky9Iz3Am7ZfBjXbYn0elKvDUOb4j0JdSE0MCb4XECq4ZXtA96bK4jfNAJjdCy29DzXblBAKlmmgx@n/pA/OiEBuBsoYPP0yC3Wz6dGcFx64XdZGlJ5/jZ2sxubq1mNpObW5trWWM9m00amaSxsbmxBX1O2tg01jezW0Zyc21rdQ06RvDNbm1IMegr7GYqBdKHIcvwzQFYp44XnWzjjTGu3i5KMc7k2DvFVKHWQ/uAyRbEkfHKPc@nzf4rdkHOrOFJnFWDAUST1Vns4GAvfXAgy7towVWNvbQsN9CS3UynN3Zl2SKfPei8M7Ls8jjgBcF8bkmnd/dkecABoNokWW6jpbSOQyNZttGyt3NwgOm8QUsG40OwC@7DLZ3AsgHBHLSsrtLYSpbfhuAg3A5PaI1yWkILpok@B9xnD/xk@fMgP@k0QDjh4TiEJ0FZd3Zk@ZBbdnbQ5wsqeJZn9Uu07NAjy32wABHKcgsMLewFZLkGRiRFWa6DqT4ywQ0vlUFVOo5vyvKIIwhRJMtDCm3WL2QYAQh3TObJkydm229YLf6M@vxbh6yBjz0clA5qn39ea7Vq/dFO6fMT9Pniiyfmm9GgX2vVRLRaFR4X4oDPRXc0/UAeD6tVszPT50vwcaZ8qqOqhXmrmm8hT@JpYSLd6hfg8wX4zJh6HXJo8HQhaA2f3S58d80a@QQP@dB3WKvJeSRU7MdxqhTbzIUDvCDZNet9N4/2YWGJxZV4clReT1fy5M66ClOv0/kb9G8qdHEpSs8oTKrXo/KwkK7A2HAjI84MKfL5MJO15eRS95Gxlc0tmY@MzFpimEPN2G4zzuKa8UgxHq68U56rjzKrazn5/NEjTS4blUcZYzO3vvFqZSDLag7fj1Y3cu9AxI6DHI0vtbxRebSRjUTZ2EiYqUxuY0PN3wBCfOiIagPfqlYV5coyL1QVM4zdu6JeU2nZiEpq55vKMDks8FyxEVPzw4KR50odWHoKGFOUBqoVGuAlgSojoC0GIIeP0jnk04psbG3KkIdUSlFVZEzISuD7@mWwoBZ@IoYJI390ltP4HaPG5rqq4xGUqtus0j1r7HU0JI4TpJd4XozOigfbOmlo5@WkMxxWYF9A4pRdw2uNSdEBDLC5MizG55qMjS1JKgqp@pjf8JQX1s@f7OkgaAsbqijSD/A2e7ev4y3M/oQPV58TOJ1BT6c/sXCzZj1w2@OnuPXSEEZReFIlf6291G6iMU5h8MDTwIMsedLPgEfCUVeT3WBmoQgms6FQ8lA29YrKWS0WC9VC1@r2/BGMK/mSPJQqiP580GW7jIfF82XB6ZpqYRcQkM47qK/QQuvyMDaUig3UxrRb2L0e5FBCvMlbBavfd/tyDM/kPXIKA8czm9ax1cfjYIdH0H9beO6q3n59XsKAe4Ds6xut2GfOuBCHHsdReLiHMnSNGRIe1UL6Jh/NtWJqxZqabxXKGPQ9vrY1Wa5oWvl9BUaJeakITTA/ipkFb1DjF1qmazBAXM8Pwc3YWMu3Wa1QezXM9ws9GNKwfAewGBmqMRO3zkJ2Acy798rHX/ueuq1lC9wtT6Ded6C7rerVwnCMqNVCOQPjODGuWzdgbJfBjYDJTHormTGgx4WeGOLCbwPsa/CDMNAhZwwc@SkdBUZqcjI9TOtG0rCMpJJ@bTdeMzXpuyUHqiudy2GtQY2TFb6mmsisdJSGy8xtjQgAWECeCmUm26xnJ9sKxDqxzA4PrmqK9vbReiKbTrxT1fxbyHZ/WWnou@qjtXxD2WVVFRxAhIAfCFZr@WZBeaVO4l@FoaiypBY86y1hG5kJ4aO3BJUlhrfeoFtOsyXAwrVW1W46pucvGxuZXHmwXNYMKG76fWtb/m5RrkDF3TAJ/qLLZCCj5MEtYBpcqhnLJWO3HgqhHQvq2NjK5EUQqSfYmCIreBU633isxOMbmXhcjedxVmcJ3AUbJH4VBwYaf2g8kkEuknPyVgb8x8zvVg74MHEdxrM3Eo7kGAwYY9fSzfXNdnR31JdsNDITWmB9yFgrsSyxFO1f0KsxtkQmTS/S3NtOYad1spMXoXf2pFiONu6Nt1axc3FQm2mppU/dNZHYLr7i33PcIQTJSqS9q8wqYtibWYVCNyJ2KKB3LXGs8p0zqe1EkaXOJVmmps9XXjezKs8r@xCjmzDY3nVT8KzcMxxMMsXM8SZdrqgfntud681VjQ9IFRb7wBIpnTZ/VVMfYtBt3BCug51@X77OZAH7jhs4wNDTB@YIvUw2K@Msk/Wa9U63Xm282nz17MXRi6MD9jid28xtTk0znz9OJo24Ed9mj0HWtU9KMI55z9ys8cH5gm@HjOVjuV58dS2@Oh21EBsW1oKldcUoFjVjO8MeAa2yHPCvprGupd8XOeEVyWM9Az4ff@1na8PtTbBnQKbMAU6ziUyxaKxk1Fjv47f/Fg/0XZe@2nnK4qhe4W//7PcyG3/7Z/@K1nHjN3l0y6xuxCAkGo31jdj1de/6@gYe7peNVWI8T2sbKpj5HgMjVkwJZ2PDUGOexm2Q3WzMey/0rSiZ9Cb47R1xm7wO2IxtxaTY5rPX7xnbhkFmsdFq2RkypVK35u2XczCQg3/2AefpPmhLrwvF5RQQAE46bmGEYF5ppVgsruCCAIsXE3g4NZOldYnyTb7C@MQPjmJWHPqzvBX8Q/sr7rDieWAPvMGKc8LbFssWDQYjn1Tq46/9Viaz/rd/9pvn6vvq@@p3gPVubW2tG5nYLyEfC06MBUMXmvTAs19oCIc8bM4tfHpdlmI018N4@GAAhEMePC/Ntc2gTbrEnppQXAU8miBvKhRsBc@9JEnypEOyal6SQvmMJMt@q54kGGwFVZ5C25GupQfoBR0WKwBvkh6MQYFDF9XU1KteZ9DvkZCkUDyjkmQPIQqk8AAVGyzReR3B4DQjz1Irt6PyLHMdJ9TZs67leajbCPiv9ACiPAUqpbtTWM/EM18Ykt/HjkEon@TRKEPaFUi7wyNUyVWh0vMAScZzxyM5IHpKD/AAC8mm0BEzexsC5JkqPQAEQBkUAdiusG22qrJrO5HIj1Uh3eAuLDwHbwYnSiSMhtAaeIwqiJzHcDZXdzDoowogJmq4bkUdAyAcBl8uKIDUjNHJhsIKHRq7NyiARYeHFSoae/hwnKtCwW6ojEqE8FETFKpvGuutuZUAAAvGG581cnKSOYkEVvaDSbIDjCcou0B1GhnGgZp4tAetN5IE//cmWqTIqaoijzwWQNQXbxV1QBlERrTzOqyjLisjs6GyMPN1yHudMkUqMcJB1PnwM50009R5Fm@kX8YCnYES3nEcEfkF3U4fKWLAlwZ4iwyel@bMQBwW4vcLIHM69IPYYSwoit2h0E27DzI2LX0EyjWUVUPFaM3QhfJBu68yaww3RmVV/FAsDI0qGExUZyDSWaJpXdID5fVch/Qf0FlS3D5GWqk8iWt74NkeOFcmaTLiqdBuq0iOuHoopHzSXuRwFU0ej4vLLLU@jAMD3CSZ1dJJ0Udmiylc5RgeNHdCcCpFogzDkMlEHNc6VheydGpZDM/ge7lUqmX77UGNDt0/s4Gu2gc2dBuOlxL31aSu7As7dYaqJjW3CbKqOOQVY1@ZHTvUfyNOtpP6qo6NF8xjtSoTp/Q8lllPgriXBMyOf4DYHE5K4km8NHgneSj4bcBngxs3k5G4S8pIvf1dNZaUqkpiAakm6eOdNJemE8EvPe8lMUjzRl5wBJfOhIFdD1kutEx@DieOB3HCA2KSOCtcoHOsOs4W9xQQp4KTY2gEEdO6hBCaIWEfA0yzHhxpw1YMpX1AHQC1PWhZqKPC7@fwrGcBtTcpdWh6gsE77DO2mqGbvvnpZ3FYGWBg1RcmoYMfRMVyeH4DKkbnw2/gK9A6uw3wi6HKFk5@GD@gbjSTvpYxebMlAQ47HUqrwHizCCzZiAVbB9e@BUVfAs91yOGMnCwpcgLAJmRV5qDD@NPRObVLxEty7DakJEMIAtUABUWFXdPj6g@FgomrqyuddJwM@rZueaiX0sO7tlK9lg3SqJvyYZQtrhSw8T4YcdfV2KRxvbR4NdujId2ItvVwxL@S1MRTl28Hdt9S4k0vjn3gJfDKXqtLB8jxaLdHdHNgk57WukKrcZ4gs0wleR2QWQ7JTNuM3yAQxhDMMDlK1pMALFmrXySbV4288LikdgfAobKswBHVj/UDS9cLTHavGYZwfdrIGdhrnYu623FR9JD5LOM4aV7CIOQosAp7zx5CJMe6Yjv9vjlSyF/F0EinyoikGzaC3p18wAi9CbvmWnrsYXlUmYg@DKND3xWMPVgfj49L14uBcuVI6D/k/kPwH3L/4TjRINnysMIlL3S6weIgcaM2mCAkghkFYW64bqexD0EGuZgZHASGHE243cCvXqDYAb65DeqxEBAG0ASpVFNQl1v5vOJ41tVKJZFqAU3LhAiocQBdrhBOrxqhGbHfuez0XG/CyUFlKdD5iHyjU70tqIHTCpYxrCAiDI4vG3VqtLo6n0Th/b4oMEBAcQs8UQLY8RVbzYfaLMkTCKcsj3HMM1YWmamQkCW8hBtIRRz1HLFRQJUIIHQPiwTZBB8WtByhdVgwgZd9vKAxCKuRWnxSyxmvxAGTU02Fs5Q8VVIkV5oWZBPQjlJpYboogT9URXnKK1LMG1H/0ewvfXL2m9AuZueeCJb3C3kp2lSsIaogtERzIayyYiFSr5CD1IrZsfrQQZW4GCo6ZUhmJRWMJng6WASuOlOJVH5d5fVDe@RlR86FpDAqFKCIowJvlrxdBCjlCA@jeSLaKCAEEZ8zEICRnhnNEtGG0WjDQoEzDjacE@0qkskhZXLIo/DQwzmZrIhoMEgKlTNi9VRQJxcIVDLAM3hvifonZeaZl6hklL1BHRoweArSHPMcogJBQyhJI53VKzNTL0cyHWFaUwCQEG8BaPBLDnLSNMMztNAW8iiOyoBHcZsgA84rgMCIBee5niQlJDIa6oJcLyeoH4C2KyfKkmzgbhj6S/OfnAwcg59x2zE9GdKYdEwnp/7@QRwriNlIA40IGUZ6DRkyDlh2SG0EiCVXLlNmCM/gngpusUzVOm4t1TVxYwFedxvebakG4wFSDPe45/qm766t5fggyCb6eiGCs4iCcT4GsFuOC0ONqB42m@uNc@KoHq/uthzbs5J4myYXwS1aCuf6oKWo3CuMridJYtaPD0sRNCcgFF2rVbyJpVpVPKvTVHOhkkO06kiH8biE41kwReIDHxJAj3qKi1cJ@@rdMFFJoYh2ZtcvlKOe8IxDIjsMmFUd5HnwbYOowjx3PBIk7WEoGtd8hbRht92u2wLxDjUDYuwp8Idj2Jghs9ejvCSZiUPUXESVIzUHpZ40VRH1y0@Oyr7MKKYaxs9MAphARpL1p3GMmO3PSK46NzkeLUjv9NPzexrN7@ni/NKoejrPfKhd4J6flvSqMoYAAcfZWL07G0mhiPdWdiayEjqjAMUj3DuLDdq408Cc7kDQHRFcbwJ9JEObR@pBRMa/mof/xRUYRC/dt/pMvJjqdAT8pov7wxTSB@8Fiz8KBD9UkffcTi4k7f17pgVhQY5gBygrgLxKjMtB3TPQMHswjPbkcMlDAL6D5nGPzi26p407Be45I0/9yyS7yMyvov1qw@qYI6uhiJDJCNygxCcwMiN@db@CI6MjpufyQZ0CnZQaVVyLSOeBcnNIxkxeRtQW3wrDg9gh9dDMN@XwcD7@0P8Wa8YpuwKffQaBPx6PkYZrUkjeG/VGXGdfh9@aIPgo7394TeJJwbsRAngQy/vJcbLqIvZ5ooRFukePEIbVJ4tM2nmCbsvt9m7X4aeh6O6SQuVGIhWCWp7QKjyvxu1FNR6hioAm@XrO/UjyLqK7N81FSI0DG7OwvU/rQm5Bxt0D9boShchdFtaY69ziCehG827OnF6lOoOhhjGJ0/k2jatJvlAlHAIfwhcnkL6CLwJsWX6VE1RQNpyjEvdrMPLpmr2I1CJcQBoHKBEsBrrjKRuRUFJghuDXN2Ga9blp1m@lWZ9IM2wBk0lGAkn1iSRFLWD1LKqCjtX053Bn9MJBMnwWsW14HNfs47TEddyO5@wki1/Gc8CQ41Y8V1KAKccb8dw@Gbx47pQMF/Hcl2AYt634@3guaBYYoA9WMjxGd8HC0V6P5/YU9UbyUb1/kK4ez4V1CmEecSthBFCB5QapEZfMHFcU0@9b0LGRUJlkSDFeEsdJNOGSpF8a/rkeb37fBHjinOUKBWYJZkx0GpEeg6cD3Uag4XFGS86J3rx0dEC7b8aK0sE/AYO5aBwCD2J4LD7JjHjG0JdWKOALGUS@mZudI2ZMatO/R3ZE6kChVMmT6RP2dJIHGgr5lyFwRZ1U0i7iB/U1CYJX4P3yiZHn5fNWdoLkKEe4xqrOyBYi9XV8QaGwrqduIOC1H60hmrueDIQXuQVBeC0R2AhPBxmOFtswsZ7bmyQS8sUtb3Y0Ds2@8UaJ1DsVjbiCaJlzvMlZlAwZQ7Txq4uKE4mHWZtgQehZTld4Kwv7BeLF6DXmdRFJlTc@yEKE50ALt@oXFpLtvjBSOM5uktRXzOuGgrg8SeJck2wSIuuo8mBg@jz1cPBaQkUInzZ8DWIOcVJFQQCRmGEqnL@6nyC/u1x@DwTqAAlTCcwSrGd3pbfF64W97FTOO@Nkb1cgeibZvjpTOApTGKMcRgcRyXwRrd0S8XELBxfyeaIh9ClpP0BbOCa4A2/TYwsOC6WE/uWk40UGHC8y8xF1WyLpXOqB0KJjSgIOL3iY03HRFueVF3xWFaMPTWSbnU@u4P5kBUcrD@FRAfpTKOetHM@v4drWuG2T@kx0QZZq5Bhn5LT8GVbz2BHYPS3Fhsuw4HBUPdk/ev70G@h0NzY2VNFHj8b5w1aLk6phP84h08bcsD@YMWzJJFF9NC5e013teDHi0rkj3@IlnFmDMIDXZgTkJ9q4KnhZhJ9PtV2Ix8NGMCpgXYybgTnBlVDUMbHLtgVefUCI5SsrpgASiLeA7ySN1lSckwXqwBu4qlXqvqpV3IxUrYpeDKsmWOFWfxlbSg28Pt1Ix5XbXkkSnTZl@0fs5ZOdM3b2pMQOXux9yb45esFe7jw/w9Oaxy92nx7uMfiVnp@W2HhGAR9U@I8DSsDrvlW3ujVg2Zl0eo0R5D23N@J8R9lTufup2WVP3LqF61Hbntl93OYW3bH8Io9VguHoSFyuDBnt2r7PL8uqAzgSbhp0ZAs3tzMIW4MxbRfHvF23YTdtCCvh2LdnW15wuoh1bKhB4LfB8cAkF5Lw8gHaCkQXT9GdYXjpFITHRRoAY3rjS85sj0ewGjoTiAufT8bgWenk2Snbeb7P9o6e7x@eHR49P2UHRydgPf7m8PnngM/D07OTw90X6EUBnx3tHx4c7u2QA89AWmd4HpduEVuUBR2DE1bqF7jETTdMhrborDMEAwmeXZl0eM1j8YGD3Mc2O/Y7qxHPS3gtCT8wR2sCLLwUjFlvcSkzWPOl/QTyC48u1lhOs21KDRpLEdpbXjRX6PZQxTEuPHRHDC9YsfJ0TFYh8/jiFtqU07AtJu/hnhOc@@anaaktB6AhoSWAjaCCDSgFRvrC4/HkNoEsQmr1jotKn3hqfFOgsGDUx8HWkbxEGBN7XxAobqs/dHA@yMiHDkD34JARyfp9HoCthg48AFvjDiiKHuJeEJYVIQb@0QDZM1vnDm@6vQNa/2UbocOuSaPYTZEnXm9UpSYb31xrd3sd0vjOZ3noIhfTq9s2RfEoPGpM73SC29RqFpA88ERx9w3uVYOQMjCbJi41iG1szoAaNvgO8JZ2r202fY8pBVVnZ7jZx3Jsrkq/1TEdvqVpvBWHaI9toq6EgthtbYc66hv82mgiQLw3YjIfYbx9IRVa940HMXdvpWiKPY90z0mwpeyuDOzeysCvAgYAaRMjnTr1VHSOEcG4TUHKiucCReK87YdoeCDnxqBuTUQI7rp7Y797pwokJyfGScG@Q8odVBFeC5jka5ZNtw9tnNhqF899IBest92eb/M6VCZLML6pCEJjxwapvS4UJ1Kj2wmnUnRcJ5JoDah4Tqo1IMr7pEoUzxfJQ/YVtPXwqiTaR4fZMWvupRVZO0viItKVhdMvIAjza96wt6FrO4X8KY15xwe6em@zUNzfPdc@vE6ionfOFvjlRsEmQn5VXxfTguZB63y0AbGPcpdoacFtAd6ghrHFnjrBLbGVB8BgHNi2YVz3uJoP/fj24dvueLJk2p0c378v8FgacibOkQdeWxlztyQrB0kmKU6Fib0eEd4JmQVerwQuSYIZ8uvHeFAEayEPGHGQj9Alm5Na@gULCUpXGzSBs4h7eER1h/BVVqStE4EgSY8SrY/UK2W3kCiqqfHOERZBpxKw6GQAGa/pGe8/of7qFrj9xeCAf98f3ObC3PHu4ZOg7S@E9kl50xLzYfFuKQLr/mA/LADLO7dfCSyUPTkfMO8kb0MLKT0kzuRyLNwduzjF17fqjtoegMG@F2dQQqCR1AYOLVEHmhkVHkGNghkLRKdn@6WTEybz8QnEBb6HQ4aGYIMIe4lfYsB3z9oOMTs9FJrCwXIoPAUuE1vXwiMfCxrzTOTNYRVCBkkKfITMYvLKQOJ6omchEYJ20xNDDDA3mbvrgAd5ZQH4BlVxAvOKjcWwsIDSzGLGeOdje9FN3QJvSS4bR/fk045p3nfj5T/9URRQdPOP2cKTIrPr7yWXj3NBOlzAst4OqMANkKTx/kudnULCPQio65M1uKBagirFTfNcwI4FuMMdXulJCfvvTlBESFwI57JwhK0L4VhkjcvHy4GYQzsPsRswcUun8OQ7lMEjYPHksh2tUHXc6SmTXRAImXgtzeMoVUD0yk0@vMlSGfeThVAgj7a1ZcpNOchlBWdnBez8/ECf4d7m9Wn2MJ0UcNuFSWl/P0nxXmIipQDnMwsTeALk9Wx29S7Y06UIomt/V9i8D5nmn363B@P7MUhv5NH0PlDu4fNk4D8mgAWo41vlgwYzFRFEnRl9ykTZqTOK5g/ywueFIDOo7LTexkt4JlNV2XAqb7Oh8x4pCp2C3CpDpAmHBeWt5hb2bxYnhwz5zvSWPj093tgwEO4RvPlleLguolAk4oTHRCfdrH7foWD8WFLXxeNjdBpp4Zk5OjTHN7TywqAnLbNFC9AUh4z4ttpkMMVAidCsoo6XduGkXn56Vk8z8tESHhw@LbEVUsLVnJiClPuyGmE5S7azKAPEemk6AnsNOor3mZeDH@QhGYAENNGhPIVwo96ZN8IICMtl0iIvtn0KlmpMV3rTq5sOardIynTf7UOISJOvpaMDddaEejo/ER8y5/UcBWIlZU2XKSq44TwuQpoEwWsT3SP9lIRa1MUGyQVXfJopYzO9viVR6Zykn@yWtyrJlXpBZtDnmk7XG/SvGhctt33ZZB3We1Mb1kfv3jKWXWN4xDfzkKsbNNYLeLpVYXgr0SbbShPBigw@ItWJ5zJjpOYDz2rH2Xj4nV9CTXjw0Fg5hycgpqiUrXQDKsSTcn6hW16vFJxCOt8tO5U8ntXzEwU/YSQUdHgInSewFr4gX/Yr2JX@MjrbajmXrD@ojWCUFJ79YHT2A/t3nOESe7Zpvpy2GUsPcLManiHRHetKCa8vRsqUUP6RHtAhHgNPe9N0Mc62NGzIAWA/CcKqN6T3SJUepPVBz3fJRySkIQmx9/Z76UFw6ihNEwYQpGxXguxsE5xxGAXXfbjriO@G1gwujRl41FGNgChjTOJ28rks4xFAzKg4elWuSJ5umfU2ZgIvqntP0dj2Nr/B@ga8aZIOd2qYfTr4kK6gEdc34NOjxQRMggRzj45vSFB8tBto4C40BeXTeRfa6C6RIIg@uI2bXdNxJIq/DQjgiH/ARSpdzGAKwQrkRH7Uj@YOUJna5LgeVxHwFCSvlAdYWITN0yuMgdOOb8IRJivQBO4PrhCdHFfwiBJoBtluFSMMr/LghBJahhY2D3FJVUpeRfx0xtGUSDQtiBYEjqDiwZ3YwIksGP08s6D5jNie1elApjkuHozRgUY6jivST4Tpe2VMsxJmnvtrt/y1CX@d@/NMjUPp0H@PA@WigeTY9TjcDZPHwZK30iowkk10qOm6DhLHOGx@UVhP992qPQ5cDKuSU2XosT3hoUV8Xs2ofe6zNBEnJPDQv8z9BX1nRM2HuZwI@3gyffxKooIs2hsrtpJMUanu2J1HvHMKfZDMZIZXovPoWN9EdrxRiiOTgp2AgIbT@NRsi4UxlIQRcBxqM3Jx@7GsC2HikTKdDX7o8FbDmtFGIliiNBOEuCGdL4R0yHspAoJgIqGxoOUWg8gjEXkUAYuhloJk@aHFWw0cijbdxAt4jPE9voLGPpm5IFxstucDnvMhLzw/jDyJIGK6S/JsNE1yEzz2wR1FoRb0IuO0R9MQZzOJ55FJ3jBNix@ZbuIs91LIJ6KMIuAUt/Ae@ghMjwMYAfnOq0L0vJF@mVqRPjdBhO51rCHbwVGESaeppInz6L7l@R7qNkJ9jjA87/U6uKhIgt0VnXgWujkyWVxNGUOMLKPp0iFu3OHhk2gS58chks6OEPIV7v8Ye3iDVovff85QqxGwVpxQsX1d2nFGfL4C2sxqhp8Kt9jA44uiMJhvRTPBa463HrqzHW8F1yWQxTyQciRe1CZv32K6HI@FoLoq6NJykvSdgV2/2Pscl2s3jPSqEUHZpVjtTeura@ODUoCkwCOTBnE1a6xJUmTpt86XfjUEmGRPsaP/CmjTusRLWqUd6DEooAfCqWf1L62GLkknVrjGi3CRlHHhEY9Nu4N@nc/dgGyFl7viaV8vyVe7gMLwi/0zXw2u01JYUsI1qfFiMl1o30AEBgdKmi4u/tJ6BJ7q5/jASF3LB6SsqGwyS7S0LPJCsksX55kAG6a4p10sPYRocFzfrkPN0ESV1AFQfJVjnBi/ijqSE0iv3jHxkK8@KwN4@mWMgSADwUrRojxIYk38k/IQXEAfLKGbQc2kgPu51FaguVt9G7jvGMFUKxQtkneo4LMnh6fs9Ojg7OXOSYmB@fjk6KvD/dI@2/2GlrBxHZwUnrInR0@Bu4SL5XxR/Agc5J1TiCmTh7Tz/BtW@vr4pHR6yo5O2OGz46eHAA3An@w8PzssnSbZ4fO9py/2aXEdILDnR2fs6eGzwzMIdnaUpFSDaNI4Hjs6YM9KJ3tPwLqze/j08OwbSvHg8Ow5JoaL9jvseOfk7HDvxdOdE3b84uT46LTEsGDS/uHp3tOdw2elfR3ShzRZ6avS8zN2@mTn6dOpgh69fF46YbQHIFLK3RLkcmcXhqqYEpVz//CktHeGBRqb9gB5kMGnSXZ6XNo7REPp6xIUZ@fkm6QAelr6zgsIBJ5sf@fZzudQOEm5AytQL3svTkrPMNOAidMXu6dnh2cvzkrs86OjfcL1aenkq8O90mmeSU@PTglhL05LSYb35VDSAAOwBf5g3n1xekh4O3x@Bn3Gi2PczqBCJb8ExEAudyDqPiEYdzlgaQFJRyffIFTEA1VAkr18UgL3E8QpYWsHsYAbJvbOosEgQUDiWbSY7Hnp86eHn5ee75XQ@wjBvDw8LalQYYenGOAQ91t8A6QDib6gUmM9Qb64EYhVCig3SdXJDg/Yzv5Xh5hzERoo4PRQUAuhbe@JwDm05ZQUmSyxXZwbMLvRCZTmbadLC/UW3p55mT0XEyo42jvaL4HEx/VnyWP3F9DpbE4pPor6QUcTeoJ1QsFMw6oNWlXbabp4VDSMxuc3ul4riVcIqDA6Z@fSglskxDQKRYjFqtWvdqowzj2tVtXkfWJOZOOuGGKSe1EoVZSx43LlDTi/k8txtG9PIKr4UCxj0jY8XF7AkBz5D/nGNrNrqSyValgiGp7BR8DBDJHHF0XauFACnJGOMqJS/XGSNAFBdltQA0VUAvB6vYqzoLjvkQK5Hryc92ML7xsiDsCc@axWKoVjWMqG/c4KkuGJkGYDegnFAnaTktQ9y7poKelocjjk11uu21BUNYhDYX0YBrYU9Y7oNas1FV2bjk@ZpUVloS3dC4bdJMGEq8sCZUzUi96nkin4qvr0UYPccNUNOCdKSdFUtJibVB7y6LjfKMmEhgo8PEGVjCLfs52vD1/iYC6dWctPuf9/7T3ZdtvGks/mV8CgLQIUd@2moFiyrRtn4uRO7CweSaFAEqSYUCQCgBZpRXPOzMP8wHzAfMo8zKfcD5mprRsNCrSUZZLce5JzYoFAL9XV1dVV3bV8rN/z2kJrQAy5CvvdCdU7oz8fn3EBWGAUUgNQMpJAF/W6UUdZk@jCV1DwAgtROHnaqi8C2tYBJSDHzvyx2SduxtFobkIPbPgvXxy@Ovry@Bg4J0K7ubu1s90u6CBZ31T471vsh6KNUoywELZxENPok7FKnoHcQyvFiB6dkj8RcL2OBTE@t5o0eonhGrRVRtZOCfkYDjfGDBMTNMCzA8SDbVEcjYcFRa@5K1MIwMkM1cXRXPpzkvB9EJWIBsRUZbygWZvjP9i2Xv5qiesBCQEJiVGsVqBcUC6I79nHyhCUdBsKs4NFaraiYw66pnFAJ11kHYu@s/RLaNuYxZgNFXG90rRTTQDi4TIUlrKamPDK/iuFC5FzXor1BW@@EXqDx7cSjo6C0/lxcpi8BjQe65p4HJ2eOcugT6TlswMPpmhtTfe0b@FhvitA0dqTU2Md38NYDQTKGZoMetZSw20dDmS5S7JvfVpyrWumVIzBge20hWLlN1Bu3nCklbYKAyK/VXAJi9vSsUoYa1e6j4Iq8laHo1DozKDpF@GD2v8dcZLT/j4onNB6ii0jZN@9MEmtMq5AeyWkjK7UfYJxiZFi03z1Nm3mxpyYCz0wuaSZs/cMoEBmZ6FevKUghQMnBwFI5HiuYa5fbXB24YPm9NR2pTpeh0x6l6FjyV6htopb7Z5VSOaqqAsU/OFaLh80Gd19ChWtp2wjl4jCBVysu7Aexza3sd50VeyOepkOPfQqJ9K8YEPUZXJqyNJSi1/CJBm7TF9HOwJR9GbljVzZMqJYZhi@3Gq5bTO6pTlgQRv0eYCA5o4bLfDZFDcbLZGDhb@hCHYYpRp1ZtyKJNxcl4wuxwG287hPJyOY@zK5wu1izK1TmL20Nct5TEYh2ElqYZjGCETm69YA67TJXmno6ZgS6VVD/@WEw7AHfMSlStQ4mIdAaLrG16xX/gJhHt9v3Hba@Tqi9SDb/8sJhR7sJbxThtOYNHfoBTX9x3GKEWWGA/tQiiWxv7QVjY6uqqM5/KG@qjJyFcQRdAYKMJkn9N@sVAgovmT2htSyTyf6EOkJb2TeYyW@4BOvXf30Fp/knNmDQQFw8AavU0UMQpBRbsIrvNurjeDD2HBfj4Kobx7LwW7a90M8ASLxezqhbVedXkkEuZ6fxMECpNBefTSvUxsd55PpxaTzbDr2h6PpyAddAWNoz3kB4uOCHjH@5zCaXsWUpoQ@9I1C/UX6zBFMOKIX/tZXY20jylOcBKFj3ogn0eLwggMR0OEtmplZmmdSENVwOdyWrrO5lVYqZD0cyeKr6bZX1t1o5lXmy2NsQJbVwdJlPXspJuT6Yrg3tm8V6H6ogAFj16pavrvCJiwD8R6giG4CMhArYG7dgJuDQO1gJcQn/XmlT@HsIgzlEzwPMNFH7NDrio8ZC4HTf4SX0k@s5m7DqMoH@XMMaYcPi9Xobu38ztADAL8A/OZGHrXkEQIF9B2oeD4xy8wSlxJg0em5KqgJgJI8jUZDUGzHmUY78@VWs58Xq7BBRiawNUvEtltUiSvSAeEbs1o5HWA5nYVr/fijVbJKLkWGwB3xMHEaqwk2uMtCkxY/3iPy4Q0ypmfSsmMAvQpVPcASpqtbMuA0QeYovHevmFbrvrO2hEAvz6jJyBDg2Gq/JB8HkXnwZmUaATO2l7An1galOJmGpXtibyXvyA3ylYfrnuveaWrKxObN11vlPqHWW@Djol1YhmeJaLIYI6MmoCFUoehZk/kyEudeB9eb11ncgYdVOEtNdPSmoue7z2sfN8V3aDOqNhq9pAh2jHfZ1u9POjDwzmoOIm2yiN8hjtFBltFZ8KPR1BKaNJbujyGiPoF9CR99wBz22wfcmfOzEqnL9lgqeqb6lImXiPjEUN/oFgh8KRzg/T8GIuMrEs2kOKp58AQDu9JtUrPaxXi1@IEbRGeVoJqehfApYjpZS3RE8eQHTgcNVprIieDpwLxk12HiNcIojrscMMile2dRbZ61uaW5bglkWSr1oZaURzP8POnMqZVbqIAlnoMKPaJbvOni/qP6pWOBctAC16bPYkvaqOBgXGsdoIF/zE@dOcrAaVdSM7OisguhQ6wB1gKoIcNxwNoTSn@jiCkeL9hlGYFoz68d/LMuNTAA9HZDYxurzPsLLOIKunm1uVb1gKukBMW/Ef2yFFnUJXUJGggYYqjvNaEFjJBJ0OPBNAV3MSkvA6jMEVT0mrgs4SUF2ExNCnO@I1KlwOaWUaKRV2LPbKOa2wgIFvllUkBAZskvkrYCG10uLEaJnfzxpCVAIFa0zxiHqZBZyeJQzxwjEB4JWs1RTppWpSEUTB83t9zMR03f9HWvYXxtLH8F/GgIT6rN5a@7jczXTLetVrZqpibgwzV7zXwEVLgmwJor/LL/yPnBjJ6tzRINJSMjZYgp8ARVqSvU22rfxdY@uf0qGUO1Z/oeK/Wrw0k5MvG9PxzL25JI8e1fPlhlG6kAkeDyFPhMeVM4rA@SwGrjTo@jQkVXhXLTHvBKpZ0OrK/eHB9n4op2F8rU5TKIthqNBtJw1wyjrqx48fxiNK1nS9cHs/G4Hl59En3VrRPrx0zQ43j6RCnQAcwIrIm4No2GnEoAYYCiWLoqnpKo6s8GAzNmP16S4dzBrHFJcbe3aP8ZabOLr97QAQ81KfvrOQ4Qx3du6cV35bOcKa2omxCojUap72x1gQPowRcDtATWlyXUGPJlZU8D25brHVzjBoKpMGiyKBCue50ayNofB@PxtGJ9PY3GfXRFf3CzXOH42KzQ4CJ4yUXuo7OYAp5WrODdaGw4rmIRk9SxObUvqcQEKsI4Rln/Ihi@mIeOffKtDbsKDHkdh7mOkY4rlj20XQk7fo9mmQ4B7HuVvvRDp0d4Wi4MO70s4PQJINpoVnJVn0wRl1KMCM7uLo1IzQe3RtEAYOguiQIqKjpNL41kRXGNXPt03hwgDhvchsCEQT3uVwN9mX4/rvguGQzuxxQpoDxP7G/OEOlEmlagLD/AJ8Zj/qcqLOvjpYgVLN9g2ofbfAcrdLBCofC45/1w5RweHlqPwvV16/DwCB6qVevw6NB6ji@Ojqzn8PsIf695ra2tNvPc5@41vDxSL2@sI2iDDjjXexfRc/gJ3zx0TEJ7YZziR3XvUaX9qOPtH7Tj@snhEfqNw9Pf/u0//vbv/1k/lB//hT@O6MfJt7pQrVarP@pdP1q7aePvk@dnpUfdk0fhWWnYRipDdv9lFPtj3zBgrPUKdzjp9Mej7irHHW3BMYrJWhAt9hz4x/NAA/vxR346TdLHKH3EsJxpdX8cXvhU3aIWDrzSYWltDZ72vdK/lOjsRN77@v17eG@5yMvJb59Qi6lnrMPXz16@NCNfI9cn6X0QYJgWTJwo1yajSTyCQZ0XVc656olVq1lnVetcg4emBh0umAWR1UwG5l8FSDU6sguh@1NRG/BilI6@@USe70ku4yHJd@ronPNv@aKpPO4/4UsdamMdGB6Wb7O5tLhe4vABXLyF8aonze2ts2qxWCzonFydHrE56i2kvnSOJnWNS3cw7AkUwpKBsXNieMQFNIjIKBYpY9NajzOLORNUrUljYoW7WDLkeTxvooEUNJvjE27250cZCxU@yoJlxTNyBEDZYHHfKyUAgDy89olxWZyJNg6D3miw0NfumBQh7R32SvTaKluDW05blh11bRnXw0HaICAEpQAKF4ONLjfIyJtC2RFxOx6j@g3ixm2iOpf409YmTbA2Sgmn48VwDJ05ZM4TXwF3Asy7MlnjifLmwh64ZjcYYCJ0XtE8Yak5KcLdDfAoYtIDBbOPKYrGGBaKBT6@gqSAiLAeUMKRFGUD9EZwxhM2YpkO4BE2fHTk4nRsRIbruKUKQaFSi8qxSnEmfKAcuq4VcknEKvxOL4CJPOgIkvRhybWWuQoMXamJb/eF0kLMLoeKtISndGUl2bRW9AUsSJWXeEGGl2OAFCxZo3RWwBoW1vl4cq7Hz1dqMWbEo/szTjhH3bT4jhw4lu5GeWxTd2yObvPhKiW/mviJoDecxvGoC8hKFmqaKAof269H0OppqcCdCbXgRR0iGF@VQ72izPEpUgrmIbmIM7wP8Gh3oqggUxCvFfFOjO@Gi5mb4sl0UiWW2w2SUY@N@Lj3h4oXh3hNS9b7BNjqjkB54ItKNcHUw6kKcCN3lDTVaTuEJ7SXx/V/oUVvn3Amx7zCosV3AQDSxKFn5zRFUtqipgRqIIsUgZFMkAWDDzKEOQ6GoyRTpyJBANjymUdxo1CPi/wcATaxu4RZtNWnVdk19plzwbcyD0DGq74Bo911xf82j/bUYHBX49yHuiYPiVy6dm/Th@ZHChwTaljBgD5cvpXsDNHminsdxTHDaJL9LKla6Sx8sAdqXEBkflEmHxNqQLjFMk6qJ4CN1hI2gJ0uLYOUCzcyzRsEjMRt7uTEo5bQy9PFIsEt5q3oRUGKRHBT0F4l1//f/WamshuhiywsPiiFdAB7dGrmoEM5LDeZuwKvAiWoS3w2YI3RDIOisfmE7CgYRWXEi9ToVMOx1JUausxwlSSlkEJ0wM@TkjmXS1XVeNPaZ9na1RJ7FV0r3yLHkHRCV1yO5OsDyVO/vaXaZachunqjXzfKu0mcg7TNhJodQTltr/4A0YNWGJTmR0/OTR5pKB1ecXk1ZpEsQLjMNE5t0RWNlDMtUXKQxLYKh7Nk@jL59WV6Cm8sd336JWX8BLnABzFYRATfrcsTPKIFrPtrqQXIB0bACNiGyo8DeC4UWPIQDdN@FQ@PpnOnUTm1T@1Kc3vPtUlP1nJYsReDZlTsBRywC7MGiu5JgQHpXPtdwCw86o76/WCiwoFCVelNf@pIsyd4nH@t2V3MSVZtYuKBbfDyuAqTSC8E1/QcRv7w0qfHz6ZvIn/xEjYh@vn5hOfzNbb3BWxGmBaIvnzBa/SwD6KGfYN6ckoT9xoiuSz5IPn0EhINOBicIS7kICC4hQDuU48/zg7WQIM5fj670NIz7ZswqecsocRsyHvOFyfnBc45e4lJUTv8DmjTMZLSyiN9WsqULDICflA2ZsZbrsGi/hhveoJJ5h5CRa8VwuPMxVyrYo2BQBtK5frwUKZsk3uuoY/PRbFJehedy9k4GcnIbg1LjQsrLaffJXVSZUxekYKXjgyXcWeMA9s9GcEqTXUZYlQpFkQJU60Y@qNCN42fjh1ToUFUFY480dok@mjctD8wNyzdHyhVAwNDGBc2SjnFcRYMdQNqtwvpPmvpUT/MKB8IByAFwSiHlPuYWPONOcc4wxi6gpiJntzfQmf/e1Zy@Q3dNqRYUnoper@CyMA8LNX1ybK9YjXkEtvQaoFSOPn19DIQzVbUCUN5NRKXcTzH311hvUNzy0h/BqqU5bApuzzMLLSMcKhMNg10aiGGdmZzFmispjBiShLEckLxzWc8S0s37BidyzZYKYGSDPOykK0kJj3SHPYGTdzaPCtajLj1yVXSm5aAqCjQVF8xVdnd0o1Nkl7jqV66gylYszKlKbJb6Qaayqw5SrgmgzsRFdxGVPPnIYrhysMTf/nV0JRFQBZLN4VCHvlq1iGmWeZa114st/gSIe6hFoSX2sgRdLtjjFuXArbcHCaNF8l@TwnDZetwCGwxKwuzhbWfvmOthxXIeMlrWR/EsVX8LMK4rkWQrgrwP8bYBS51iQc6mRMQEFnrBV2IfJQQG4RvfRohXvNWvegWxGaoXuRMNc2dpkud3KMndAL9BeI9s0G8ihnccsDCDYVEjrLVESe2u3c/2utWHEtnxpd7JA0cOT2UZvZcDkM0Jr/rlLpelGgKjgXNW671Mw@o6aykxXsQnvPUi4UHAAJLGhjWDTqj2utywBsHMAwdFJKPc1MzLNYP1UH3H@n8W@FY2SoIBWgBoaGkA5TPKAsxT7BICORMSQu09DguAaq1K0duL6moRuIioTZDyWoHb8pWnXsgpGeFdunYSpN4Rolxqph7aqpOiKxibjXLwSiXeJpBV0dBDw/C9SlV7BrnwXLsUIe2JSk0gMXOerrJDLsyh7O2ZglsdGS9JGPkKvoZRDEcGWScTpg5L5MuMCF8SYiXLQWWiZb6wtzzBy4gJdLVuZYviCB7TeWQ9ISmnuJ9NtGYz8cOVf0QfsgZYrrk5EI4IY6qw4@k0BR@KkKX8XkHkdKB3t8Plf6kmbgvqUrq6FW0yHvxTpP3YnPvWcR1PG3A3Qf/jnrsa0rOjen@Y5VNB@AHvP/SMQX8wwRK/gqJdmQHbh8nrqS7fpDqdbU46XDmbs1@UY8Tk7t@H7ZjYLbk2VQBPTEhGyTLwLMysCUn95@0YSolnbsXVggqJoKyrJlJ7VQvs0gxM9Rf5RlPmBqIK/EDaI7Mi8ibEK@upj32TYcNCr8PyDOd9Nomq0WoEHHFE/wpLn4PBhwpbyArmUdglTvSrYxB4KFBsIx1FPnJvUSs9EqODfZ18vplOoxrBevlTxfJ7iOXle8tlxXLdKZdTsWzcjEE2WLjZ7bx28pp6QEttGNryG1cqHSATyoHoBgmaIwWxulhvnAt88rt54t9f4ovf9SNofyHF1/KGv29rBBTToWYXq4QkxaQWj08eKN6ujyxB1i2E9KQyyL2cH/TbH@wblR/09z@OBm4lZaTylPqFl/ndJtcTaWGJlTpkM4fcztCXstr@tyWtX1uObcXNM93ug1v/LkN/2Nvw3WNCwx4ecdOY0z9n3P/jzD3GEJxvNvYbXR@tXtf/c42Ccteum@1LPuh1Tz4aOd0/rxxOt/b/PyHYlI8aNW/juBvUvyhuL1b5Ed4gF8b6te74kFxH4tt3xQXdc/z4FFaOTyGVg4@0W1iqcU@/HOwpdrdXhQPqh5V/7F4sA0PzVYLIDmdv9g7ne828H@7/UcSP8zbFS18rGo1pLgqsiHwXaCYyJNaPo3TJp8Zu8NLJAGljmcPSHHnh0arBDAaz8xbuw2RVYCAOP7Du0BSQF0GmLpLH09RDJOE4miwx4WK/yC2elwJVoDuwoU/1AXt9iJ6pTEnVLgJlBJSoK3zx7VtvLo@lzAUGgAdeILETDblBvXCoY4xxBb@PWh8ZOvAFE9siVthmxb/crcpu@Ku7Ir/W7TCRXIxnbRyAqsXrWcwXUlgfRczLPFkFIZBwhL/MJgEsCXjYfpoioIOZnrrYV688eh7Nv97ohq3etRQ57u4w7453FAtXFj2o6ewskaXpBW9h1WpnvF@bHtT/QLGjTnD0E9GedcMR8nFrEsx8d9Ei5fJ5xSJoo5xtROOSlEHWa5bv/TRcIAiycdAYlAC2EE0m9QptxgIbOgrg@HfL/3vATTMZwpD63egGB72f@9Q8tA4CMnFZT4Y2JSpJxj3XwehH/kcNQ2t5mf@MHiJgWFgMuILG5WnovUZOdckZnRcrSwRxkEOl5RMVY5gRbw/Lin3T0KtZaG7MWWMsdFPXZgQ8W67Rl4TUMtm1wLKUj2YTpO0PHuN6wr0M1uDYoLBJLFrCF4OpiMCbo7jX1dArFuWvCA40p/SafqCOiJoImuEmRxwVMFkdkm0ozOrnjSfnEncNK9pZLgmi9fdJ5LV3LYRoThNctjc3MUvM7a9pHvJgoQO0OMAwZohgYI8ITO6LbwETSGOp93vKO4PciVYkEh/NfVNlj2Z0cMjHnZPgqFPvOKqO0qoQH8UUwGsWR@@B9mdUVTJkGp3NoxrvBbIsWIUx7Nga2d3kwCiHV8V7U97maKtOrQc@dGiTsBdJJdjPYq95MIaB@@CsVivENgUUZYXJdEZJtXyZ2Mya9l2iXQAlZmRAhacvQq/e/7i@NPDNy@eV0BM2cLiMbkl6bKOgVz@vE7fB2OM1MBkhFV4@da625tM5E5cKT3FEzkG/amJ9nUTYNVAHNdwDxiFTsmjamJnwQ1bIartk2FFX4dfTaPvdeBiXG4IyoyyHdgKuWrlF4vo0hVjX0UkwUxgA6iDA1Oe29EYGM@tQit5BWBAuFsnAYocI/9EyrX3H1arek09oacqMNZq9YAPWexn4xEonqUvZpMMty3R2vGtEjA5vP5n1vawRHyhZretCw/1@HbPa7S13947Z@Ze66zIA4TCYcS9mR4t1Pw5M/FMswEhLlk5K5fJ//nvktu@SYPojJ3Exej/1ntPBS@uMVN/welSnVLcg8lKoNr7WhLMk2ccbdJL2rpCd9pfSNr7Z6BV9533Zh@h417DXr2@3vO8DfcauoxCjEIZAjMM3kCLbhvfDTLvtItY/fR0gjmQy@i6982rTz@GKUc7sSBOTr49Kz@qV0ol123jEHyP/Puef/7qr3jKH7k1Ou0/jqaXgpfI153UYLYv45PGGUFfsXFodVyFwDmHQSKjj48Wb/zhZyAtOSUfUIBmSeQYB5My2vfFv6yNtkkoc2F@EBNHnp2dXNu9HnpU6iIKBm0@q7iJvXfO0G0n8OfC7GILuvBaLWo9gUoeWjUtYX00gd364zevPvVK@76FrXo5q6K03tXEAYRCBOPgq0PMiJQhHeAqRFUJe@sRwcB/6yX7IDuW/bp/UGrf3KyE51OO6QrCTykl4L4zqwjFRd7tKW1HKRUswsDDF7y1/eXFG7sCdTEEC76c4Pa2IKbFTqye6oPJDTkFbYGL11jG8zbX1ugdVpnFntdqNFyMiHIDrcWYwhya5YUVtW8i3@s7GpF@OMpJ2NOqtersyBLXm9utxtbOR9MItggPc6KvxcBCPNRa3o2SxRrIhoGnkv@sgZwMu6n3cLO8@/no6J@/2Xu9/dzpdT9p2hX7u5jM9qPQBCDyr2osFgGPjSTeKwGBnos9vx7630/rm/1GDyTP5k4/2NkKdhsbu72tYGOvu7e31xts7nb7ezv@zlavW8d441SldjmagJRkM/ljt4P7dbtKMNttNfYGg2Zze6e/tTfYazU2Nja7u1v9xubmYLfpb2xs91u73b3uh6W2FJ4CMFjFd3HvWObAj1cLd4VbvF1qu/8H)

This answer is based on the code [provided](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51144647#51144647) by H.PWiz ([test it](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOjq6Cup65gp5Cml1H8Py2/KDEnx9YtMac4lSs3MTOvRuNRR4OmjW5IUWmqbUFRZl6JAkTNfz2uotK89IxkBd0Iv/zQvMzk/JTU4Mq8ksQKsFEIWUw5hf8A)):

```hs
forall=False
main|(∀)<-True=print forall
```

Adjusted for polyglot ([test it](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYGOjq6Cup65gp5Cml1H8Py2/KDEnx9aAq6pG41FHg6aNrqktRIwrNzEzz7agKDOvRKHqvx5XUWleekaygm6EX35oXmZyfkpqcGVeSWIF2ByELKacwn8A)):

```hs
forall=0
z|(∀)<-5=forall
main=print z
```

[Test all GHC extensions on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVVtb9s2EP7uX0Er/iAtoiG5jtOZloI5SZsAbZMmGzbMcx1aol4AiVQoqlVqG9jH/c79kewk16sDszYoi@Q9vHueO56XtEyenwOqkI@ifpaUHRYkAmGODHfweowMgmTF4yRAOCiKA5NT58AE//GBxVSln9m7VDFJs/IQNdCgPla0TD9WQjENYKgBvKdxGlxB/Hvme5jXP2swU8rjW6ogLn7gZeCc6BApp/LpR1QGzkiDuawV4yELL1hEq0zdVRnTIE81yF@KIkuDVr0LoeU1cHS8PlT5BQvSXBeiq82ReC@4yIUskrTM71ipZBqoVPBDuKvTHsDvREAzkCfUuNQl@L51oSflDn8IuKCK7jsAY1AOY2ygI3TF6jeZoGqXn70jB7oYbj4zCfaQm@ZwHh@G/koHu2NL4EmXGbt/4orWehJDXS3cilJFaX1TQHxKyEOHI52@v/E0EOFLb8/PfpoXQip0K1lWhYx8m769Ou9f3@xmjV79NxUPwFv/XPBSvdjZ8t4t/cpq1b9ikoUi2K0BRkmR9S/rgBVNSZAV/h1v9hH3ifiy9QHbJUnBCeUBQ01ZpCGing9vNDRb94gi60sCPtDC972Fl7O8UE8Yo0n76fj/w6GK0RRtbSMp8muuWMwkWnhTBK2G8KaxsGbaq4/qjh82pTH1pqtqPAbbDWEek1JI4wgEjc64V/GSRuyWyUjI/PqmFyH2ALcrSB7@umwMz2mWrTbYl4h/J3FdbjVCO/dtQKsmoG8bC8/ZkP2oTYr9pUVib9aYrpvHBBvGHOPZeo46Pun4teeQpyPqldVSSQr3wFm60D1IDWvQ30iClt7yU02kV1RAn2SgYsZ4rJJeCWojSoADhAvHfF2b//7ztzXBJ952jbRHrTOm0KK/8OrvQr3yZlCWttN@odRsqG8broYNbcSGzmBDk4f3EYxTmA9hgI0L@@7pvNs1M9NAyLCd2um7tstc23Qe0vABWbYSlxzS5YzHTdYg4@0Ufql1PPgpM0OB6AS3BTBz56QlRe0EFamdmIC6YzTbmlvYxI9no@MT5/irZZFHCFv2zLA/tc6GJDSnaGHBQoQcGAM0GpLIMz9ZL/W3CEJm1/JK9tiqndOUt3oUXUiWV0DaVK@s8pmDuqDCCi/wJqOl6jX/RbOqN8Mu0HXW8cT40zfmkLgN6vwH).

Answer (score 3):

## 263. Template Haskell, 12280 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:257</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=Bger[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dmint 22afbont:2: 6 16l{Ex=>+$ f t$pshow  ent
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak) )int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num (a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};q _=r$  (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$ f 0$ f 2 64;g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+50+z));f=(^ );(!)=seq;
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$ 172:[u$ [-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPkB3ua97CaHZN@@d0A0ugAUgGoCVWhUgQSazY6Z8casxlJ45fGsYzRa645kyyutHWGtY72Sw1I4Qnp1KPykH9Dyy4ZiQ/MPZs85mVUogADIHkkRWySq8vNk5smTJ09@nawZbvuXv4zgw06czqjVcTzmma7HGn3ryuxrbHfEnhiWm0mvShKG2um3Bl3T9tycFGE6Y7Z5zQ7tutUAN@Y5l6ZtvTP74JdmrNd3Wn2jy7y24YHFglhs3@y87773WN3pdg274ULIVcZODPBsDuqXzKi5Xt@oe5Zjg9caYy/sjtGtNQwGIcx@r296BD7DAET9kuJM@qwz9szpuyYmXzdd10HHDca2zG7PGxXBkoUQRt9yjnaefz4VeZOxzw3IWa9jDqfyoqfYS8vsN6Zi6Dr76vzgYNo1zb5UHZsd3M2fvspe9F2jY0zDX2M7A8859KbdM2ynZdoGS2ubWnrac53t9o07UTZY3zQaTatjapZdZyprm52e2WfowppOH6rMMzvZVDZV3RnH1OoYNzv2nAJb8B9m9FsueDpXJhhNqImeZTZYs@90mWG715CSvpkah0ewm5PkUIcMAqGxNy7EbpjMta1ez/S4JxTX7JM3pMw6ln0pceo76TuNQd2yWxDOBLz2Bh6VyZXqEK3IeoKGNTSwCGGBB4MsnDldM1wXLhAv5NrtmXWradU5csyhZ9oulNfVmAV1d211OqxhdiDCGHo9wVyHDdyQU61jtLW6JiFyMRXWvewwi9V7Pca9oBiQpYNUlpld543F3oF/p@2yYa/LXKsL3l7daTZNk70ze22IzroNqeFIDJ56b6pkgW3ZhDC2CaXbO/kG8OYhOu0mZK3BaqFwkA/KM5XYsB1AX5/ZRpdTQ703otIDmCBG03E0dG84pmtHPXbt9C9ZzawbWGxMzDVbTWPQgRStJlYH0IHlsq4DX6hEm0G2ILKHuEDYmJg0syCYjF@9Zg8aJlavg@QCde3X8nXfAProu6IePasL1GF5UZeZhmshx4Iormk3iDJ6AS9zoLThSmdXFjQ8QMWgT7Bds0@kT3AZlgJAGgGtKtd9ywOKwFLssBPT6LPzvmnGOJ2abt3oIZWGk4TEHEzBw4JoRJhbW9HS8UEUCJTH0IweEGR/9fw7X0gG0wpsuZqHX0GW81Lp@T67Wb5AM@eZQMS9vmLEWOEDc5MXFyb8hnot2erfSgBVAqx0WNLpeUlD7UEGVQ8ymDTQiCb1Kq31OqGE2dZUHYSaDQ/VgNoAJsC@SlDJ6oN@H7n7GKnGJRS649gtwCcUtj@weZWvp6AKgP4aboKZVybSAK8j55owfN4GCoF/CBriLLzDIYRClwNNUWDUT9d1OgMKBzFdD9sjYAWiIsTDJvuKNQ2rg1HAH0HxXPdNF4gT4wzsBtZ817LNhsb8bBDX6UNbvILkDABKDtAauiHeQpmCwFARDhUVvT7@5m83Wi2As1OvO/2GINevgNjr1DUalFno3BgSrGMbHcoWhEtg6jw6JHBldKwGcTnDHokkKBOU6rUz6DQYNdRrC5pc2wBmawKDqHsmJ3Jn4EEeE6xrXHKOaHHKhYJ3jRpULCVAaVOxVfZkD2qpDs2caEbtDrxmlqm9Eou6yVfKdk7ZXrowIXMxLbaynEy28kBw2go5gS26iHK@2pnoKlzPcB2rIfVGXtux00ytM7lecHqmrUQnYEQT0X4tGtOQUyuxvFWoa03LbijRLaDFIiQcjeXrhXrZylXyU9HDSQKYawSDzdVU6jEZWQ01iqtkF4QLDTjZV6owhfwct4ooR28t5IyImXa74g4REl2QLh0kEOBDmtsxzZ6S0vQYsgkMN7Pc6DGrpFMwRIFzViUejUTj4aITBCjpREGxsZ5bDrKtTq@N8gYgxXZ7wHP7SLt1A6jHxU7NA5EuwWpE19QTAmchnnhtRoFr14CR@nRETZI3OYyvIqMUEMZNaLIlm41QQwYmAG3Zc@9w446D0gHlCXseYB02Jmq0oGogMi/IDi8IT4lcJot0aQNDQWg1k2XVmgWNAJsb8HRB86GyQfDVNA8D0HgjCfGerjHCXo2LBuMGg32awbrAHvojVjeR5wDzMXmHgokMqP25IPcyp8lSajqTmWxjd5qY10/uqN8FJv0uubAlYeHDjQkZDWuCmN0x7NbAaAG/cGyIYtTrZs8TjApK4nrAiqb7G3JUReepuW1p@cl02tSJ@OLROA1k8rz2RFdoIHcRYrsKMhmKfnwswBpWH9gS9ORTqUOAq6nE5dcYZCIDr@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@XUReXi5qIRv7iNJjB2LG8UalAoSE/paq2@MwAxJFZey6l6JRYrr4LwUStEU9EVRcmqMIyDkUjss2wsbnBsK1ETekPl4iIKSBX4KdfbfYI3TKRjsQBVkA8UeEDWVqLaTRbSr8UqsXgU4saiCRi6FaJRwEwdkeBSobEtTSDo@PRLjpi9eFyi5g2jUvzd6U7BDQe9k9FPBu/eIe/iMGoBhXUGBpfyeiJA8tD2w2roOTVo9b1qTYZ8dCKNz50mHxXt4at0dCCZQ6qtz48PSqcFSqZtuJcgU6gtDJsEWRmw0m9owA06g4YpzQoDbANM9XFOcO4AE2/V60x1GAVT6zwToe6izuZAA15DgqfD1E53sghuG/K7N1EGAkLuFHOR/FL3s8SDz8xTkOQBcOy9s6OJKbLuJcgTrO52UPhW@7wAYE2ucMcGfYIxRo4d0hjNBgETaAvky0YwF2A7toq80B/OOeGE@IQIhCA3lLZQkrAmwiDgpjWEIXEE51OE6I8SK0r/e44Ng1NTe0ncUGbAyHG2ytRmyv8nXJDS6u64dYKkD8Zex6gDv58EdyGzCwAIHCiZnO0Ty98BPD04oHH8fWUEUapu2Ii/hkXj1IHlthG9MJbAXqDfBKziIBUndwhrh6wOUm4LMG0OLY@PWqGFn2GUp4arxHCctMPHGUhlKCNjpvyZOxJgnTqM8E2QldGXT5ewkn1l9R0bkayVADSwojzWwRTwWegFMtrZOUzvz8fvLOCAsTvOegi3YajTyK270Lpsp@O0HLYCAZA0NY0T9qGNM5wwyvGMHrQo6x0haKflwFB/kgZNM5gzXV8NxpsGhkxSeO0N9AJsdqHHAeaU@ezwuyUQQ/RMKgX5920peoJChqBMlxEd62wcQKwCdJBusCa/a/bao/4EObmOmDfxaPKQGiafyTJAhIRciRb@jqKGGzl3gXbuezV806yyl2hMgJN34XH1ROknpBXebKCEkSlndPVRMQH0ToWP6xcZ10Vygm8FUwVqs@t4RvIrDVg0viSUkFWLyW4yuhRNqiq@ZfJi6SJLNsyrJHKpMeRhyazPhD00zXoSfbFzY75hJnp8zzmouYDHphcUk399HAQxp8vfiseRsVPugrR5pqGTP28PTMmstx0mX8AQI1wyGTqINoyVVcA8CIA4LgmiiRUhyXMGMKxrmB2ra3mHNGffsXHsohHz1pBrCd894DdjACeWCQI5n3AYdzI4rz7uo@wWD38KnJygwhBf4yjtm43kyhjaM8fpw7jSZTrNKaQD1HeFR9Jxew3NGwIAHqtE/bvr9/PPj/dL1ZOd86eF5MDtJztWDXhEw6x2YTDbgeYw58G84QxhCWjHsp2uBSXyQb677Jw6jseFB1w4eNgTwYg@jKP96tHh7unO6Tcic9SjW91Bx8A85panAgQwzijMQjB1p@aAbGEP5kIC4eJ49/jIh/LFi6PDnep@6eT4PATmzaBjGfow2btszSvQFxiE6VqKo/6405hc0aFh6sQsgmA2OObKMxibMlWFt4puPFEclWnogSIydo@qirPABs5z91laT21uNmpGNmuuN@praxtNo9lorKX1bKaZzaQzKXhtrG@a7D0FV1VzSDM3YOKzIjiBhGlA5umja2u@hAND0TpILKOZ@Qp8F2SunsmYG2ubxmZ9c3PTSG80Vo10dsM01zeaa6mUua6nmrWsnl1dmLlQNlC0Gtu6NAMErQ4nC8gTmJ8Cn4nmwDMPst41a6TT6fV6prm5mm5kUmuN2mYqk23U9A2jtmmmmmurelpv1NN6zo@LM6rAJdpQYShV2iCa@l6qDp4xye9Mw1VMq4z@MrRgOMuryGJ6/jIyDhyExxp6DMQiMk7NCvcMuvtLyDhFI9zX0b2LC8hjSZasgaMImKWAuI6s9Wu@4yY6BivIE2urwCoF/5zlPz@SgHyjp24R@DWuQYfKd6Pr5H7lNZsTzmlyvlSxK@uMnVfJma9AT679isLe8ZoZOIC3RvD4yvVMeHe8ZgYO4GU4PFzxng1uymdW0ADYOgHDFfKZsKY8ZgQMIG0QpPCq@tgvS37zltRFWjO950YKYG8SbL5aXn3DVyuqYrEcqZk3kHOQxI4ckJ@PLJy3b060GCkYgV9Isj@NMDmRNPZJj5dJmHo1e31HDgPizMCyLx0aOAemakrTMwglANG97NyN2YShBr0mgt7J1F0f3n91a016zQiAne70zBx50LSn6PqhqzWSp/TBCdBZOZicyp1IvmY2BzAKStYsG833BFM3sxSyWatZ84ICJnDzgf@dESzHTgcwEk1ra5ruD3tx6QR4Np@HPT88poA1gwZxk/P/bAL53qDvQSzx/a/fa0Al3K2itjGisWBgqNrmNdFHc26Niahoodfs2h33@oQYMt0Hsm7gkqvRCQyzQVPtq2rb6HdxyCWqGwgUX0AJC2iN55zPxfjf2YnkGCF5cp2B2VaX1WeEprBTSyI8MRpkdxyjQWjgQ2HLpEh9rGxeDeaQDwpDAg/0PPMSmrFywcZbBbz2wBvwN@4OuK8arR7@FjVRETKVMWq6CSKyUbPMBZXeNy4HDUcFSY@KjBlbnxF2XHqarFObHeOSG6tonF18XsC@1WqBPCG@84Jdt2FsQ4PS5DV97qML1x64PbUGleVBwyEbNYXughT6Hf6eF8QS@@cCw3ysWR16PaDSA@IicgGRjhCNW5rUENKsKTR3jNoIh@rtT6cyTJAEHOA5hXo8nlrFbi9Y@w1vRZofH/tKir@5OTs230zFUTJreJXkm6hUPoFMZRbbqu6pWOi4rK7RUdONkHEuR/enjsemGUFp3katdwwXSMsT1WFeQfXRaxG5Y89Uh2FXf2xaQOzj7PhbAOatJgu2JVp13elYLjbtzjwOOr0AN04Tt7PRKzQlbc1CbINkJretBqbZfMGpe7iUO4fQHsDl@CoqrlOHKEdz5iGt7lzjb65o0XauTP6e3dG9m5mrB3AstUMkYdVn9iiN@n2UituB6DUbj5cz8@XVOzPdJ9uAP8URHqA9kK5dq@O47Izei9DS6kM0/p5N0WEMWoat0npQ2Dw7mshUj2lilnVOvRqdltNZz7aSBrzmVv6g38Q@QXwfyv0C7qXr93MvXz5ybF1857L9y2T/8r66o6WJPi7ah4wLeuBZLEwsSs4vIIwkcCfO7MIdpLIUU0vy8fK8CujX29fGyP/@Cj3LPOz6PUtvRPI2iH8YYTMLBq/PZfBfJbW1xak1Hsae7oDduK8Qocq97JjQkdH7TpWydEr/xBh6KvVwZtXsDMyBOZNXHdfemLi/fcEo5OGZSoliLIvZTpwRwrnOINQ7MX58UK6xD0fbQgZjdCxo5PdKOjP5XQ9k9B4OuU/AcIKGuxFb9qA3UbkTozj7dDHm2j2/ZTuNiUyiz6dypOz98tSEIO@a9Fs4uOKDQVzbKqylUikh34TmrycsiwZdq0HcNxZ/TyRMLuOUx2FxNqQfMs5OYzyVClVvXboqTmo@jDul580IUODNzaRt2aY3wve8KpnFbWuO0/mUKgSm27BQfgOpFBd@7qvKO7KR2A3GxnMfLs6c1JrzZj14hyRGp4A9HHgvoobw1OuDqlnFJWtopa0p6@J5oNBE7n2pQDdPk0t860RnvuApZlR0LattLGyRXJx1ambH4J/h@toieJva6kJ4gcgi5GRa28L1ML4CNl5RjUzxrd4IkGU1YJDTNrsmWReMDozGm4Hrf@YGGjr4m@Gt0XrjvHg9CxiFje@J1baQKOU5NgzLPKPfMnFc08FVceE6jzn7s@ozkXvYNVomP1e1iHuOpzpw6zAfDY6Nsyc9cnzXWR2i8a0fi0kBGtOlOXL970yAz0Z1qM9B9/6puql2X6eNSvc1dC05czHhHlnRbjttu222@U6gwDaveQBFevxE3KJCQP5b7Toj/hTepRTGbMfpdB6CWeSPnFs6TnNmnkp4TqsBUT8J7siogYf43DsFCH09IYg6/Xntpm0OoMtyHc/pmSrZ5gXt4GQRf8/jov7izq86C7VwhgAw4n9/Vfj3jk1bhuP1evSp9joDl14UVaXjdbOq8oCSeQhVWB7fdsTp1mw5tXrbui9LNdPwbOsy6c8IcevCkW0vhAWLqfvorHUsQF5/pCE1FML@Z/g5nFelYnKJd1uBYXYd59jeoN8fISY8x2Fux7ke84fJ/RPBNC5ffUDDvByIlcEZ3iQN4M46fwfZgiUQsZA4l8BICEeBWzVTILDoc2eUJrZ3hlrH6ip/zZOLpspPmQqt337KlKjY9kCTg1Zo5hbcJ@hnYjF6Zmdltwct9y674xP2DRCx8DWzpndaeKZ5qqJ5pUIPZNjiMw/f6U4St2/Dtwo1NzAXrq5kFi6vUDi9oxqOBZ8qfKAOB3OnzTpWz@VvpjbTMwWGu0vId0ONZg@bRf00zCZfC0HTfZJe1@njISIQKdR633TrOJWOHJnLT5z72E4LOLPaYePAftiZRbi7aj2z@oMeT/36udkycHvlkYU7LTszqAKgTi9e3wf0OwPDtb4zcDxzJrzpBez7wD0zWlb96QTmfWA@RsUePP6ZIHt0uov867bl0vkN37BgzgmJjJMt0lkV5P1Zo7Wp6frgYPTiaZWQoCT2fjP1kPl7xAMDLhigvzEzrVkz8U6Pxo0jMi2ahLc8mpkV35lUNXsTwKLkrwfd3sAVn9mp0z6d8BR195Lc3WsL2KL6Frgxaxsdb/Y0dmhmFmQu0UmOjfOk8O9aHafFvptNMRDRoNNGoXwGwe1Cd31ieNAi7BkETGk/cKEUJz3UPi/YW6AJc5Wplm15iyd4PM@AMZL/xcLwzgZPISaP8K09@VQI6vlsjBwtlGCgbx/VO3go/lNHApztAhWe0aF1NAbn5sN0L5Ix9wRAv3exzevweG3hok8Ou1THHngq7vJf1KesL@xTcmyYXQ@RBlO@U3r2IhamENr@ep8casJAcOB2RmPT3I0HU4Rn2SCszefFk6H90cS@SSoNTmmj5j1xdnp4eopY/r4za8RzMoLe58FDJuhABt19s44rj/em/dx5BqIbdGU9YLrdUxO3DEzxktkRMdqRUzc6gJ/GvcmcEdgZfcV4cG30zBrUb2dsmi2LzQK8b3jGHNmJJg5pBBiY7qUVq1Mz@29oRjBknjeonczQU3NIw5D5BMNboerV61zgxmm5iTYyvbbj9hzH5m9iwin46M8WMxvoHuj18BV3DfcvT/R@Mwdpk6U9vuLbTcwGP7g3r7h9s@Z0@BuLMIcd2BbfXGD0LdNNHln2YEhuTAXZbfYwh2/jTWkbOM3htqGxXVswxg529@JmNb5V2J0aSYFIfGW4tOQ/e0wzsZP44buK2ka/7uDamTB84spZ6EjYPXw82CrNtybUoFKGwNCM@sDXK3BPVjvdWpdec8ckoZo@NWt45K5G50c9YzhLiJw8OiYcpw5v@SwNG/46U05g1BO7vyObHrJNYtzq0YsY@vVMMvGTe26Z9XdG7B5eGrQimktOGjSindmQJjfBgZjTMVWvjXssk543j2E8ty4HjQesdfkLKIOuiWvWkys3c4nKcdtEEc7sVfqA4fZNsXUbdwlC0/fNyHXVnbkki@Dh/3j3iyR0zNX1NTzBPxiqLWBn9@8LgMwP@rb4PITsThzXa1rD4x6qcXL68/gLFisDUeDDmwOaVuYVAurTHnT4fEcrtKOr26DxHUiDTQdMHWLhnqma9pVKKo6G/nJl3/D1yMytw@nNofo9u0Ov3WA9EDzUnkvfZM89OTw6Ptd6rr5g5hA3/A2sDq7uUVZ8NyggmeZPUZ/RXrXF8ub@8W7paIcpDWAyjh27J7RYEO21jZrpGUlj7jgHfU1vttD39PzZUXx8aJkpe@2@0zVjYe@9s7MEZIR9cTbTOxz7AKi76QznRj8s6XpsBvm9sGk5cB7Lm5HSPEjnJoxWgZie8vOzd2CJU0WkAClQleEmxHk3cLP64ky9q/navMThQOL1/jEVcDTq9QFOS0F70RgFVBQjHo/FJBHrqXPNuqgqCCO5dMb10urlWco3YvW2oTun8HjKX2HLBtsqsPRaisViea4wA2gBCHpg5lnT8kHvuK7VsiELfg5I1xHqQeFqlFwGYwbPh1sus@WbYS6V029Zgck5mVUqPMf4UCKlYY8UFZ3y6OVlo1JYjqpqdDl6YedYKhoENzswVp4Z3JgIC5nFj8hwgF@uxMwhDWQBNvNczwv0YahDqW3YjY7JBFFA@ftcWwlXhXOOe5//4g8aQrUUqVDrWq7RAYSgdjigz7Zzvc3T9dHV6xmomgphXLdxXhtTV/d2GIy5vXqba5SC6npxcJ4VemqEKjqwnPCZyyAXnHJw@RTP3HqcMHhugvOTIuEgll8oGMwNujZITw2v7WrszKLjtIP@@ICMUNBne31cI2kk2CFrmLjNlE5J05Jgx3Eu6eQU5uQv/oBr56Gz0uIMq588aeUKpYhHonVSiVOvOwPItQ/kndl3RBAFkWzUvQEuwJNSOHKP4QliUhsE1K76SnMoGa45Z2/njKklFkV1c6jkIm81leWd08@/KqcqhQ@smzT/6/eSsRuBOPkzdXPdlRPMD5K/RcIKe2fAe@wbZfLyUOYJBgfJLTFcu@b1garyOJHhWXKfxhyn5zcblP9Jz1dAjUJ/hoJmqmdfe06XdKYRwZrXpD2HTiza2CGRzj4XGhhYYwSat7rCsjLga8LqmccykCBqIDLAxLWs0dFq1ASDUZaH7D2jTgMGAHomBTaOyA4qH@oWdv1DCKvhwyHJfbM2oA3SV2ktnSlQcZarha0imUDAcFAJWPnVxTCdUi@GG6UKDGkEUi8uhp@l0l8D1p0@xHqcxJZXer5/s6wVU@/fu8aIyfJtNM8PswCbWL45OTwpnZ3vnL84g1q49VnbAT/S5vMapCI6pdp2OqReDfCCY4tP4D@BbcwGUYFnLCaFzxNSUIFrWZWXuTHEmiZi3xN9VnzXDPnfDSB4WtNiUtAzABUYRGyINSz8oIdK4piIKxRdEZVZ2H9gAwoQg0eGZvBSQpXMCoAsFZD1QFSx@YXd5m4Pwdi9UBajbXtmEMRYkF458OdFnImC27@XcvcM1/27l5tDWVxuCrOg3BA0cPXjHOwcHr04LU1G8zt54rqFzYw4SMuZM7Y0Pj7xNXuR/goREdfUCzKTKQK3is6M6xc1vWsTiiWYY73LIxOFUv5laUyYgJkCqritCClEUSgHKN@gIDJ9zhcGD6Es@n10CNwNL2LABA7kALSfcU0WkCOkqlXDxy8GQhXo8pveCTFxwa@jblj8SfgtDouGffTA5W1uTlcV9Doug/9Qr@Sb0hU2ZKI70ytMZWn4dUy7BQX2w8byvI9iyxwR8jLPuxzkF1VsQp4abwxaxqLzK@J8LPTSHaPn@sJghD13PDPH3g4c0sHhM5NAviDtrgbXiEtVy/W8km4PEKJhzOD3WwTv8OCsgNIZF82Iv4dpbmBjRwWBuHJacUre66MSZ358mWuJ5Ch3hEJCv6ukqSBXKCALpASXXVmuVetw@mqijNMBTomlEQVHBcekfYXtdFyQSRrQfYOE4mFXC8KJRocq@clK1WZyBGhSC0TGBJMlDOsW7iqog670GkcEr3nkZQpHkN0QzOjWkqoC5lqW7WszzqF6Y5oFyTGvP8A9k8XonSh@FnJkUttetxMKOENV54WZ/Pibv83Vc154YP6RMA9Tu2D7dWFrgvk3fB9dB9s/C2xpsP2Y214lscru6iQc5zNQLzH3GCoQ5xP5TsGQMfh6nalAQZVjdX91eMLcOqoLxgrtwkBtXFfIZvxxCrO6QBlXVNEYnKcwrscxHKX8FdAJEBcQCco4KNZQema/oqB6ulwyiRnH1S2NNq@aQ76hhLTVvR2gllaQxJLrmfU1PQmZVK98gKRAp4Vn6TjAWCwHjFG6snqF17U629raYrJbNzpmYT3PCSS5bLxalV8HGV2GsBIfLZQZxIEo4xjgVxTRlGUjrscwKvZmUT2KjK3hcHoDkVAhAwSJobPtq9wAmdMRqAJits2hR2LTyB8FAde2nZB6Zh@QCoA4bNQlOt0mx@fjcEo21Eq1cDXILzEYzUnk5FkUW37FLrwLuyJ0yjKgvp/PoF8bzP9khqJZTlmoUuiuhlNlWj8ploY9ObMdnNk@gNwyJZ1Mryb19ViIQmUBCvKL7f09gIQWDhyjblpvnJ67s1c6/OL45OyOpisKGZ0OFmXR4lb8QtUS5UpgiAb5nkTq7kHy7NnugY/KcK7Gc8sYYrxZeDqbs1Kbzumc1F/yo4h30yaPOwnpqYcCpokp9YA23d@FPvZNhgLu8ZNQd1JVYje35cpW8cKO3En@/SztxRFtBYkLTBcu6S6OTmcTsxjcVHCONxW4mn/OXsdD9nj60nMux0f2hUPIgwf3oQAHkLSkH2oe84QMHPMZoLFumTS/KsEl1sdniUinbJCjUMhz/1IFbFpjVYhCB2DbcNsdqyZBB95AvZhcg4@voibQ/aO5vY7lKTGJpkAKKAYBE1PE1QrD3FCjJXGFNBgTrARbpFbQhxeToBEAvOjJwG2zE6cXmtvaN33TKUgjbH/A10tN9sWgC@Ga9Dk1kcWaIJ@oEBkQFQ2yykfV0LKEVsFhHDU3Qnpl1C0oCq51GxllGNPa5rBhtYCBK7EEtPTPdBCrAr0HWGjSNGhHgcdxDH@OJ9DCKP0k5ZLDMXCjbGiW3TCHCmpLylVAPkX36PXLq2hMvkMDpOFyz9eJN6Xq0m@IhidaxFhN5FRj2wzuU5jSRbq5iRqnUIUDVAukeOb1j8AI/ZPS7Bo9pgxIB6vLNEZW5UKxE67XjzG1yNW42Cwep1E1fMgDpGYM2iQTEQ5TcB5SSRagdtDVtRv4eWf1WFnXtAqYKZEYW8YZtT3oynEuKibBKAmi5AhsAeuW5TBHnHo1TnkQB/0lUgrHUBHpDG9SHUoTtQ7igkrNio9DyrTGLZBjdXMzJ2pjktVsMiCLu1xeSwLYGSzEl1IBv@JEPmANVevjHQy4IANs4cmXpm2bgCCgma4BfbAxACLrxxL@XSqJsSp2SiHCs/hUHPGHjE6qaC9Fbzq4ar@czNPkTP4W@tTXF9ipNkW3Okr@j0ktmb9RljuFURIEnVhRWW4X9PjqSjy@bK8oyzZ29Y8f45zO7TJIElUNhkhDCKQud2J5oGeQPArLdn7Z2FKWG4X0CsUAKwzSbiDCBzep3Swbt8nlx9BTJ8ClzxuvsuySls@Upum3kD9sIcvJBNDMDSpFpItUMPllKx7HPGjLVczAh@TFWZx49sVZkqaP8kIaTba6orlNcdWgJu5cI8MRKJxFRQNjTyNjFycrqn7gsYL21Vl@c2QPnvCXeHiN0X5Z0w2L//Kkz8MZi@B3UVLAxnWqcjWrgMChAkhEa8KIxYCZ/PKXEX2dycry9vpq5yoezaTy8NLzGyzDPlu@SK9FWOSJYXgwZE@u3FzsZ1tXzGym19@qatlqam8rJ5cnJ18PR7ELJRrZO34l62sQdINt0u@hzwZLz3nYpz2RyEpSiiRX9McbyeTr169B5MWnXNSKfhCtEiur0UpZ2RAO3eLGxkpiPbuSOH0SrUJeoLgxJZ2OnTHLSrILq@c2GvBz2nStkRLhD9vexvTAAP9MuHWHTTIOd8xWa1AyRtzdigzwc@CJuM@@@/LlSzS8pIe9OxXxIxyiABfJVY1MhDKZTqX/4k@WbhM3J9Wtv/h@N2ku4ecYPz@6fYbmMz3z2dLSZ7u7a2sJQBw3n3z35JudnZ21/UTmpJzZXlNTS1t//mdLS@n0Vjq5VHFdvRItX34tp1NrsvYXvxetnpx8x3Wx7vBZZToY8Z2Fn84yGXbJ3sFz2WT4T@Z3jZDZQHOt@Q47SBCWC8RsotHMavTsVRTr511E1/XIiP6qVLQlphe3N/7bT47fRrxIMZ182YevF3kbWc9GuBEMYFv1bVeRYmQLg63fRkbJQqEAxo3/9u8hfvELgIM@oy14FTM@rPVRpKgWKMr7SHEdDHo6Den@P9/7nhQpDiETxeLhAUsX0yuCTPTsY/0xmWyvDQLGRUTPrh0/IatlPjlOZ9JbaLZNvA6mDcNRZDK6nr5govJ0UYVYXB3f3IG1wYx16kSYH3Rc58ynKCYoAQiEaISbhQORDXdA74lwLy8MY2UjvpZ@Yudfhp4Jyz/Ec4r3bq0vPXm9n0xuFaGnxyeXe3JRFc0syTaysuM8wcm/PDsSrnl8DR1VdSA4/C7IUcVHIDCSLSSqHEl@K/N92NjGwk4RgUsWNKhfIVwJn7/8v/7yp3/5E/r7Kf3@sxTxd9Wo5atK0X@AguRiX765EFb7GXvGH9uGf/j5VnRBBzDZYm4yEjzFIr7oX9jIRN8pN@FTDCwUYhxlbjjmcyxKV4p8SCZZDmvpqlgMlweeZGClYvCck@FZqHTj8onyAGvc3l6CP/qHJ7Die4lchDMFufssseKCZ3EfIEXKkXKlwpv1dIkWPKcaUp0mbNVwr3IlRVRgVPH4KVApE8QNz0X8nucF/DStKmxJbQw1IkX@3p@ixCI38FTi6u1tObrmRNedJ9qreD4v/kHOywc2fLgJcli5VdWtV8V4vEw5LRdFlrdUVinyAtBbq77aAvDxrfJWwdmjn1ZFfKmVV8Xy1mRkil8pPnkSR9Q@AQDF5QqDoQXUxu3WbfG2vHV7u7UF/1v0vhVfcL3duvNPn/EzJ8zYv4L1f1FOFi@SolUWK2DXgKjBRUteIHXDF8KVy1LkBimHlSukrK6glvX1TEVl1EJWgHslc/pKejWZGX62XkoDE3AxeFqWkytoeI/dJQg8m1IEhw6bfASxSQ6vP377f@Dv4uO3/xaskDW8FZB8a2/x7@gd/r318O@8jn@nb/Hv/B3@nXr496yGf1KkwBjIasvbqU7qKqVf6pdgsFgKROV2qq03oJthKZOlRqkRS3UdvQEmE/5SYLJSTZZqsZSdsnUdPMHgsZSHpiZ8WvDXBCh9@LNSKQSeumKQSgc7L1LvTN/3VRa7kMos@toEAUvTtZS2blUrmfXe23K0ko8kLy6SXOpk6bU8qfO@vWWsWi09369Wk0j2F8@c4/H/8XE3bF343z12nh07XQf@j4@Pn10A6yrGn8TVJ/AUivEt8dmOFPPbFzkVSdYn3khya/uiuKqieT0O9JhGt/gnPmOI8C0uXUgwKn/58jpPPWz@@ip/nSdDYOWGqggggnEDxMqLnhlcIN7FyyT1pdfwXBFcsqHxGjx9EzckX15foOwII4XgH9ARtv49/Fv///p/9oIp5UoMGsHN7ZZCTwz/YrGb25tb8S7GFEVYlC34QwewY5Sb2yIaKdANmMpKrBK7veVu8FZiWxxgEdPYKlLkcUDgEZEgTUqXv5S/3y@mzZ@LKAhIMIZWxALgxcUwlYrla@ASrAIY72ktKZanXTbLNVz/g3GjHqMQmbV8Xl/h5vRaOp9fE5aNbD6fFeZlRdm8@xRT2/r6ei69thaL5fMpERZGiHnfCCBM16jnsZHnIzHMLG/5SgrnIekij6ickx8/VsTVL9u9XuzxY30z9f594FStNqx@tYruq@/fy1UZN@QUNjNgT2XfvwemE405feW5w5eCFVVnn6WLlMKm04dSbYA305PpcZptwzU8r6@8s3oJGbdvunKMlG@nUk7/IvqLH3//@xfRAm7RINc1HQFgKiyztbW@Viyur4F5PQsFl5f5nh@lFd/UY7fLSZkXl8nL0Yjw0rMbMXK9jaI/i2yx7SI0VBcfdnMbofpja5mYUhuZsRtw8d30zU3uyNbWlWx8U/wVlmKsuMLEX7lcXo2vrWysPKmAYHP3QaaavzEK0WQyelu4MXI4X3Wbr4tLHvBglfH48eomIDObyl9I1er@zvlOFe@HxNV46PcYOhKHlnCltdePlmlyMbNZKWPBKhfRaC7/hKpdz2ZYJJoX4dQocHuW3aTyR1xXspp4wnJIUKd@K5Ee0zdWoUOF/lTq0caojRRr4NpynznN5hI4Qt2xGm4DcM1Ox78Y49rpdxrXVsNckiInRzt7pfNEGmSTSPpgZy@RPnuxG9HRmhnb0ZtFVtHhtLSzf/wCYpwclXbOSp8fflV6cQLurvTmnWGahjkwzevqYHD9Fi9PMKtmD1zHT9WsW67x5o3RowfGJ5w5f/z5Dz/@/H/6@Ls//vi7P/z4uz/9xbc//SH8/gB@P@bfH/@7zQy@f/HtP/v9j7/zu@D4n@H3n@D3J7/49re@x39k/1P4/ZeQ25@KXygc/0kA69d/8e1Pfu8X3/7Gz@D3L8XvZ3d/v/kns38//cH8H8b7ye8vDvPjfw@/P@Sw/LA//h3uht874X@Hh/uNn338F/@B//@5@EPj7378F3@KL2H5pz/78//y8fv/MZ3O/vm/@fjDH3/8wU8@/uD7H3/wo48/@Mfpj7/1b/RU@PX7H3/6R//9j//wv//x/0L/f0DvP3zI/8ef/dO/@j//6v/@qz8Wvz@B338A05/81X8ESv2bP/o5/v/kj/7mP/0c///3f/U3f/S//s2v/2sy/DY3/L//8t/x919//4d//YN//tff/3bO@4cL398@wP3bfwCXh@fzIXAeUq5Pdfn2V8rP3wUb41SABuiSCpYGGXZ3ZNI8xWfDnPQZixRX8AGWXM6ms/EVED9XNjeBL1fIfQuDMAna6U//ycff@jUg/38BwMD2P4MN/rkFvH5EFvb11xOeLE5zH2r866/RUwwWvw6H@hE4vE@CMJ568h5CfE3e/GFBMEj3f6NgEI6JYH64yQxQGNzcyd1/8e0//z3yCOKi869NgEz5zuHQyxj8vV/UH2G7H5cmHPpHyDo@/vx7H3/vH3/8@W9//PmvY9egrm0mdhLQsy@e3oWAmQeEw4DrDwkHAXUcLMLgfklKg2FpC6ckJT3@@jXkfglMMOJakTKrYJP0Ipl1NEPEONgIyHAYxzf8S2ubDC3gMiRX@LI4eO3G8fLyuDQsgB8FxVvPGRqLWXAa4qRCAeBiJB4nUc3CWIYNdwkKxCzET1l1pTDkEePoUCQISDYSOp3KelqOZwv7kGBhuM8QFgKPS6/h@7pQzBaGRQT3gbIAMOK7kCSEwkvV48PiB7AXCCaEl4b7HyAr2UI8XsyCSwELGafUElVKU89Q4ajscUblRnfGcJPl9hNoMrKelfmkB6CSidD4jo9DY0AIDv4X8RVRHPr3jfRbwfhQT0PCD3fj/tvoTPFFAICrqrg3D36qirl5At5DDipOycInziEA5uIkRPkgwYHklbgUp/qNkwXShzx82rOFrALBYXGWl5fBtFWUV@XqMQwhYazWv8y5ntHHtUOSI3NMXt@U0Rk3OvEtnMsnNNZc2V@Btw7/pSXatkxlya9Iy1Gcr4jyrEFaanzVWXMivBh@Gcm2QkWIU0D2Gfjg78kTMAOO6Dt2w4kG@o9LryISi1DdQ2NJ8Dd8tAK5h5oSObwqSPGxneaxeQxNS2iJhPhq9CUHTRg08hVfbZkERsaHPbRCzfT1NRaTFLoeLIY1VDdJGJOeua1dZwhDjoQsJ/R1XHWKiQma81waW6tUyqXg/Y2TyxU@6GsbEnzJPsBrysSFWUA3eFm7trWF9V@8UWkWCY0gsq5LxaJYcGe6VDwrnUPw82Omp1Mag@HKzdpGei2zlkmvrq9nNtL62vrm2nomuwqcdT2VSaf1zbW1zezmxm2ArSfAnBK5lVpmq/iP7jz/wz@a9cx2xUcqfs2GGs2c30rFToFv/FzGxXf5IiXnaUqLcLlcTiXwL726Cm/IZ0LPbFSWljo3Khb7gnYb3uD2BsiqdKNix/cIHiY9ktgjcIIH0sDlRyY2jBwe58XmALxtlG8QkPUMEDLUwwVQMgcHNXpzcxP6SZGl737XY8UiDDvUwwMpAm2wzfzlcNVqaG2NLgltDPom@bYY2z/86vDs8Pi5tn94BuOAb1h6NaVJkdvb22awiENWkx0fH0vI/GB8t6pj/Ns6GwwG5FsD@@3QkHrhJ09vKZ1W06vqqq7qq/h/jyGN/w8Pn4b/NL4h1mpa4kcLO3hox58y25S2uKKMon/9u1ZzGiPNwtts8JhZwRv1TLqRg47dnXN99EuFaHC/anQ7ndnMBdF9wzOohu30ehoaxcaW0F5V3HK9UccsYhI3DcvtdYxRzoaR9i3uGs0ZTcjfTZ3vtsjJ6UxWvn3SNRuWwSA@DtJw/Kx08UoI3FOcS12kYjczo66n5NtbSJaSk7aE@osiLYKXoX1U8Ka8cmXLV4xRlD58@DCkfSe5Q9sTG1DSa1l0ZxIyhcfQ2z7WuTGzPjam0HiOSkyeA4FCq7bZEe4j9xx27vD9yrtmfU6IvbZBFwfu9R0YzP7qYXYN@5J77Vtcm0Lg9dRAdcpu1/Lac0K86HXxVKXZ/weDUOrWIINIFjzALrz6HceZFWCDvTiZU8pngfIj3KtC2o8g@Onh50/PQ9/z0s7eU2md7R4/35/6ZESgDDsqHZwH1g3u60fNBCC@KR0dTVvFB7qMPM1eLLHMhm/QWcTwjIKcqMpltlbJe7fb@tbjx/py8uQI50dO@oDHjpNk7OKDuvWVWszm@@bQswfsxSYw8GIJqhqA7PULu9DKysBMDnb2KlBiDedHOqZWLTa61HLTRrMG1J5L59g69Fadm9IQ5Ldl1mTeco/2QeH@WekZbpjd1PnpL8uV6BAmXlSHl1J6EipfaOBl9DjbVcNb4Qc9NtcRPuiERmADbegnrx0/gFQzDAa/T30gfnj2A9C40MHjaZDbHZ/OjOC4Q8NqspSkcbRtZjPZzdV0NpHdzK5l9PVMJqGnE/pGdmMTeqiUntXXs5lNPZFd21xdg24UfDObG1IEeharmUyCrKLLMnxzANau490qW3hJjaO1i1KEc0T2TjFiQAiBfcBkE@LIeMuf69GZgBWrIKfX8MDOqs4AosHqLHJwsJc6OJDlXbTgEsheSpYbaMlkU6mNXVk2yWcPuvq0LDs8DnhBMI9bUqndPVkecACoqUmW22gpreNASpYttOztHBxgOm/Qksb4EOyS@3BLx7dsQDAbLaurNBKT5bcBOAi3wxNao5yW0IJpos8B99kDP1n@3M9PKgUQTnk4DuGpX9adHVk@5JadHfT5ggqe4Vn9Ei079MhyHyxAhLLcAkMLOwZZroERSVGW62Cqjwxww3tsUHuP7RmyPOIIQhTJ8pBCG/VLGcYLwh2Tefr0qdH2GmaLP6M@/9Yha@BjDQelg9rnn9darVp/tFP6/BR9vvjiqfFmNOjXWjURrVaFx4E44HPZHU0/kMfDatXozPT5EnzsKZ/qqGpi3qrGW8iTeFqYSLf6Bfh8AT4z5mmHHBo8XQhaw2e3C99do0Y@/kM@9B3WanIeCRU7fZxXxTZzaQMvSHSNet/Jo31YWGJRJZoYlddTlTy5s67CYjep/C36NxW6KxVlbRQ9Yzej8rCQqsBIciMtjhYp8sUwnbHkxFJ3W9/M5JaMbT29Fh/mUBm304yyqKpvK/rjlXfK89h2enUtJ19sb6tyWa9sp/Vsbn3j1cpAlmM5fG@vbuTegUAeBakbX7HyRmV7IxOKsrERN5Lp3MZGLH8LCPGgb6oNPLNaVZRr07iMsRjmGLt8JXZDxWUjKqqVbyrDxLDAs8VGLJYfFvQ8VyTBUlPQmKI0UJXRAC8mFEBbDEAOt1M55N@KrG9mZchEMqnEYsiZkJfA9/VLf/kt@IQME0b@aCyn8ntN9ex6TMOjKlWnWaW73djrcEgcVkgv8VwZnSn3t3/SSNDNSec4CsHOgEQsq4ZXKZNyBRiPcwVcjE9N6RubklQUQvgJv1UqL6yfP93TQC4XNlSLpB0MbMSChjc/exM@XGWP73QOvZ/21MRNnXXfbY@f9tZKQxh04YkW3@NInDTShDoD7fxp/kat4vz4d84vz8@/q96GwZ5BL8gzgqdi8qQ4As@XoxIpq8GMQhFMRkOhPDIjdk24qBaLhWqha3Z73giGqnx5H0rux34@6LJdxsPiWTX/pE61sAtISuVt1KNoonWZDSNDqdhANVG7hd2bQQ5Fy9u8WTD7facvR/CA37ZdGNiu0TRPzD6eLTs8xj7cxFNc9fbrixKG3IMqublVi31mj0tx6HJMBkeFKEs3mCXhUS2kbvMT@VYMtViLTbgpISsiTPmOj4kbkiJw1eY2/xa@/WXGlIa2G9teyzeUXVaNoRN0rfhKs/W1fKtQxojv8bWlynJFVcvvKzCmzUtFYAH5UcQouIMav8MzVYPh7Hp@CG76xlq@zWqF2qthvl/owQCM5TtQP2Jgybd1G7jFFxABcN69Vz7@2vdiW2qmwN3yBOt9B/r7qlYtDMeVsFoop2HYSYPQ9VX46TAYTeOWxUQ6tZlI69DpgzAAseG3AfY1@EEYkAnSOg5VlY4CQ0s5kRqmND2hm3oCWM1rq/E6lvCckg1ITeVyiFsgJ7LC14jF0ysdpeEwY0sl6gIulKdyGYk261mJtgKxTk2jw4PHVLa6onSWFQyzfD7olcqVXK407H0HvBT17fZ6PJOKv4vF8s2C8gq4kLIUK7jm2zyhFhkXlb23BFUuRt7MHXTLKbYEBYYmot52DBcc9Y10rjxYZmVVh7Kl3re25KJcgXq6ZRL8hZfwQCTKg5vPorgQNRaDxm49FIM7JlSpvpnOiyBSTzBNRVbwsne@HVqJRjfS0WgsmscppyVwF0yXuGMU@HX0sb4tgxgm5@TNNPiPWe2dHPAh7DoMtm8lHEsyGMxGbqTbm9ut8J6tL9loZMRV3/qYsVZ8WWJJ2luhVSNsiUyqVqSJwZ3CTut0Jy9C7@xJkRxtJxxv@GIX4vg4U5NLn7qjI75VfMW/F7hvCZKVSD9ZmVXEkDy9CoVuhOxQQPdG4ljl@3mSW/EiS15Iskw8hK8KZzMxnlf2IUJ3fbC9m6ZgfrlnOJyF5p/jrKFciX14bnVusqsqHxIrLPKBxZMabUmrJj9EoJO6JVz7@w@/fJ3OAPZtx3eAwa8HXBb6tExGxikw8zXrnW2@2niVffXsxfGL4wP2JJXL5rJTc@AXTxIJPapHt9gTEK2t0xKMpN4zJ6N/sL/gmzQj@UiuF11di65ORy1EhoU1f9lf0YtFVd9Ks22gVZYDPtjU19XU@yInvCJ5rKfB5@Ov/WxtuJUFexpE2BzgNBNPF4v6SjoW6X389t/iMcOb0lc7RyyKSh/@9s9@L73xt3/2r2iNOXqbR7f06kYEQqJRX9@I3Nz0bm5u4eF@mUglwvO0thEDM9//oEeKSeGsb@ixiKtyG2Q3E3HfCy0wSjqVBb@9Y26T1wGbkc2IFMk@e/2esS0Y5hYbrZaVJlMyeWdRYTkHQ0n4Zx9wEvGDuvS6UFxOAgHgjOgmRvAnvVaKxeIKrlawaDGOR2bTGVo0Kd/mK4BUfHDQtGLTn@mu4B/aX3GHFdcFu@8NVpyw3jJZpqgzGGglkx9/7bfS6fW//bPfvIi9r76vfhfY7Obm5rqejvwS8rHgHJs/UqJpFzyRhoZghMXm3DOo1WUpQvNQjIf3x1s4wsJT3FwHDtqkK@zyCcVVwKMB4q1CwVbwNE6CBF06uhvLS1IgDZIg22/VEwSDraBSV2g70o30CL2gf2IF4E3SozEocOii8px61e0M@j0SyRSKp1cS7DFEgRQeobqFJTpFJBicqudZcuVuVJ5lrnmFpAbWNV0XNS4B/5UeQZQjoFK6HYb1DDyJhiH5jfMYhPJJHo0ypF2BtDs8QpVcFSo9D5BgPHc8kg2CrvQIj9WQJAzdLrO2IECexaRHgAAogyIAWxW2xVZj7MaKx/NjBU23uEMMT@cb/jkXCaMhtAYe7vIj5zGcxZUwDPqomIiJGq6bYUcfCIfB1zIKIKNjdLKh0ENH2R4MCmDRkWaFisYePx7nqlCwGjFGJUL4qJ8KlUqNtencSQCA@cObzxo5OcHseBwr@9Ek2QHG45RdoDqVDONATTxwhNZbSYL/BxMtUuRUVZFHHgsg6ou3ijqgDCIj2nkd1lHDlp7eiLEg83XIe50yRYo6gjHbxfAzjfTl1HkWb6VfRnytiBLe4hwaYAi6nT7oxIAvDfCeHDzFzZmBOMLEb1BA5nTo@bGDWFAUq0Ohm1YfhHVal/FVfiiregyjNQMXygftDEuvMdy0lYnhh2JhaFQMYaCSBZHOEk0sk3Yqt@fYpJWBTrji1jbSleVKXAcFz/bAvjZIvxJPhXaChXLElVYh5ZNOJZsrjnJ5XFwDqvVh2OnjJsHMlkbqR9KbTOGK0PD4ux2Ai1EkyjAM0AzEca1jdiFLZ6bJUDOAm0smW5bXHtRIFcAzC@iqfWBBt2G7SXEjT/LaurSS56hMU3WaIJeKo2cR9pXRsQKtPOK8PSnV6liXJh83KhNnB12WXk@AuJcAzI5/gNgcTovi@cAUeCd4KPhtwGeDG7OJUNwlZRS7@13Vl5RqjMQCUpjSx1t3rgw7hF963ktitOeOXP9gMJ1UA7sWsFxomfx0UBSPBwXH1iRxgrlAp2s1nK/uKSBO@efZ0AgipnkFIVRdwj4GmGbdP2iHrRhK@4g6AGp70LJQc4bXz@EJ1ALqlFLq0PQEg7fZZ2w1TXeZ8zPZ4gg1wMCqL0xCBz@IiuVwvQZUjMYH@8BXoHV2G@AXQUUynPwwvk/daCYtMmPyZksCHHY6lBZq1MMYviUTsmDr4DrBoOhL4LkOOZyRkyVFjgPYuByTOegg/nR0Tu0S8ZIcuwspwRCCQDVAQVFh13C5gkeh9uL6@lojzSuDvqWZLmredPE2sWSvZYE06iQ9GK@LSxMsvPFG3OY1Nqlc8y5ePrc9pDvfNh@P@FeSmngW9O3A6ptKtOlGsQ@8Al7Za3XpWDseOHeJbg4s0kRbV2ip0BVklq4kbnwyyyGZqdnoLQJhDMEME6NEPQHAErX6ZaJ53cgLjytqdwAcKsv0HVEpWt@3dF3fZPWaQQjHo02mvr3Wuaw7HQdFD5lPao6T5iX0Q458q7D3rCFEss1rttPvGyOF/GMYGulUGZF0w0bQu5MPGKE3YTdcd5A1LI8qE9GHQXTou/yxB@vjoXbpZjFQrrIJ/Yfcfwj@Q@4/HCfqJ1seVrjkhU63WBwkbtRR44dEMCM/zC3XODX2IcggFzOdg8CQowm3W/jVCxTbxze3QT0WfMIAmiBFbwpqmCtfVGzXvF6pxJMtoGmZEAE1DqDLFcLpdSMwI/Y7V52e40442ajCBTofkW90qrcFNXBawTIGFUSEwfFloaaPVlfjcya83xcFBggoboEnSgA7nmLF8oGOTfIEwinLYxzzjJVFZiokZAkv4QZSEUc9R2wYUCUECN2DIkE2wYf5LUfoVRZM4GUfr6D0w6qk@J@UhUYrUcDkVFPhLCVPlRTKlar62QS0o1RamC6K7w9VUZ7yChXzVtR/OPtLn5z9JrSL2bknguX9Ql4KNxVziIoRTdFcCKusWAjVK@QguWJ0zD50UCUuhopOGZJZSfqjCZ4OFoEr9FRClV@P8fqh/fuyLecCUhgVClDEUYE3S94ufJRyhAfRXBFt5BOCiM8ZCMBIzYxmimjDcLRhocAZBxvOiXYdyuSQMjnkUXjo4ZxMVkQ0GCQFKiOxeiqoKQwEKhng6by3RK2YMnONK1R9yt6gZg8YPPlpjnkOUYGgIZSkkc7qlZmpl0OZDjGtKQBIiHcANPg1DjlpmuHpamALeBRHpc@juE2QAecVQGDEgvNce5MSEBkNdUGul@PUD0DbleNlSdZxqw79pfhPTviO/k@/65iaDKlPOqYSU3//II4VxGyogYaEDD21hgwZByw7pMwCxJJrhykzhGdwT/r3dCZrHaeW7Bq4tQEv9A1u74z54wFSV/ek53iG56yt5fggyCL6eiGCs5AKdT4GsFq2A0ONsHY4i2uzs6OotK/utGzLNRN4XygXwU1aeecar6Ww3CuMjitJYtaPD0sRNCcgFF2rVbxrplpVXLPTjOUC1Yto1ZAOo1EJx7NgCsUHPiSAHvcUBy9L9mL3w0TViSLauVW/VI57wjMKiewwYFZ1kOfBtw2iCnOd8UiQdJqhaFzzFNL33Xa6TgvEO9RXiLGnwB@OYWOGjF6P8pJgBg5RcyEFk9QclHrCiImoX35yVPZlWjFiQfz0JIAJZCRYfxrHiNn@jOSqc5Pj0fz0zj49v2fh/J4tzi@NqqfzzIfaBe75aUmvKmMIEHCcjdX7s5EQ6oHvZGciK4EzClA8woOz2KCtQw3M6Q4E3RHBtSbQRyKwuaS0RGT8q3n4X1yBfvTSQ6vPwKu3zkbAb7q4Q00hjfeuv0KnQPDDGPKeu8kFpL3/wLQgLMgR7ABlBZBXiXHZqBEHGmYPhtGuHCx5CMD30DxuCbpD97RPqMA9Z@Spf5Vgl@n5VbRfbZgdY2Q2FBEyEYLrl/gURmbErx5WcGR0xPQcPqhToJOKhdXpItJ5oNwckjESVyFlynfC8CBWQD008005PJyPP/S/w5pxyq7AZ59B4I9GI6R3m9Sk90a9Edck2OH3Qgg@yvsfXpN4ivF@hAAexGaCxDjZ2CL2eaoERXpAjxCE1SaLTDqD/G7L6fbu1uGnoej@kkLlhiIV/Fqe0HU8r8atRTUeogqfJvl6zsNI8j6iezDNhUiNAxuzsL1P60LuQMZdCPW6EobIXRbWmGPf4QnoRvNu9pxepTqDoQYxidN5Fo2rSb6ISTgEPoQvTiB9BV8E2DK9Kicov2w4RyVuEGHk0zV6IalFuIA0DlBCWPQ12lM2QqEk3wzBb26DNOtz06zfSbM@kWbQAiaTDAWS6hNJilrA6llUBR2z6c3hzuiFg2T4LGLb8NiO0cdpiZuoFc1ZCRa9iuaAIUfNaK6kAFOONqK5fTK40dwZGS6juS/BMG5b0ffRnN8sMEAfrGR4gu6ChaO9Hs3tKbFbycNLB/x0tWguqFMIs82thBFABZYbpEZcMrMdUUyvb0LHRkJlgiHFuAkcJ9GES4J@Kfjn2sX5LRjgiXOWKxSYxZk@0WmEegyeDnQbvt7JGS05J3rz0vEB7eIZq28H/zgM5sJxCDyI4ZHoJDPiGUNfWqGAL2QQ@WZudo6YPqnj/wHZEakDhVIlT6ZP2NNIHmgo5F@GwJXYpOp4Ed@vr0kQvAIflk@MPC@fd7LjJ0c5wjXW2IxsIVJfRxcUCut66l4EXvvhGqK568lAeFWdH4TXEoEN8XSQ4WixDRPrOb1JIiFf3GBnhePQ7BtvlEi9U9GIK4iWOcebnEXJkDGEG39sUXFC8TBrEywIPcupCm9lQb9AvBi9xrwuJKnyxgdZCPEcaOFm/dJEst0XRgrH2U2C@op53ZAflydJnGuSTUJkDdUxDAyPpx4MXkuopOHThq9@zCFOqigIIBQzSIXzV@cT5HeHy@@@QO0jYSqBWYL17K70rni9sJedynlnnOzdCkTPBNuPzRSOghTGKIfRQUgyX0Rrd0R83MLBhXyeaAB9Str30RaMCe7B2/TYgsNCKaF/Nel4mQbHy/R8RN2VSDpXmi@0aJiSgMMLHuR0XLTFeeUFn1XF6EMT2Ubnkyu4P1nB4cpDeFSA/hTKeSvHw3W4tjVu26TUE12Qpeo5xhk5LX8G1Tx2BHZPS7HBMiw4HFdP94@fH30Dne7GxkZM9NGjcf6w1eKkatCPc8i0DTjoD2YMW9IJVGqNi9d0Gz1e/bh0Yct3eAln1iAM4GUePvmJNh4TvCzEz6faLsTjYUMYFbAux83AmOBKKOoY2GVbAq8eIMT0lBVDAPHFW8B3gkZrMZyTBerAe8GqVeq@qlXcjFStil4Mq8Zf4Y79MrKUHLh9unOPq9y9liQ6Csv2j9nLpzvn7PxpiR282PuSfXP8gr3ceX6OR0lPXuweHe4x@JWen5XYeEYBH7yGAAeUgNd9s252a8Cy06nUGiPIe05vxPmOshfj7mdGlz116iauR225RvdJm1s02/SKPFYJhqMjcX00ZLRreR6/wqsO4Ei4adChMdxKzyBsDca0XRzzdp2G1bQgrIRj355luv5hJtaxoAaB3/pHDhNcSMIrEWgrEF2HRTeZ4VVYEB4XaQCM4Y6vXrNcHsFsaEwgLng@GYPnpdNnZ2zn@T7bO36@f3h@ePz8jB0cn4L15JvD558DPg/Pzk8Pd1@gFwV8drx/eHC4t0MOPAMpjeFhYbrbbFEWNAxOWKlf4hI33aEZ2MKzzhAMJHh2bdDxOZdFBzZyH8voWO/MRjQv4WUp/MgerQmw4KoyZr7FpUx/zZf2E8gvXLruYznFtig1aCxFaG950Vyh20PFy7jw0B0xvPbFzNMZXoXM4@tkaFNOwzKZvId7TnDumx/1pbbsg4aElgA2gvI3oBQYaTGPRhNbBLIIqdU7Diqk4qnxTYHCglGf@FtH8hJhTOx9QaC4P//QxvkgPR84AN2DQ1ok6/V5ALYaOPAAbI07oCh6iHtBWEaEGHjHA2TPbJ07vOn2Dmj9l20EDrsGjWKzIk@83qhKDTa@m9fq9jqkh57P8tD1MoZbtyyK4lJ41OPe6fh3vNVMIHngieJGHtyrBiFlYDZNXGoQ29jsATVs8B3gPfRu22h6LlMKMY2d42Yf07a4gv9Wx7D5lqbxVhyiPZZFRQ4FsdvaCjTnN/jF2ESAeJvFZD6CePtCKjQfGg9i7t5J0RB7Hun2FX9L2X0Z2L2TgV8FDABSJ0Y6deqp6NgkgnGagpQV1wGKxHnbD@HwQM6NQd2ciODfwPfGevcuJpCcmBgn@fsOKXdQRXhZYYKvWTadPrRxYqtdPD@CXLDednqexetQmSzB@P4kCI0dG6T2ulCcSI3uTJxK0XbsUKI1oOI5qdaAKB@SKlE8XyQP2Jff1oMLnGgfHWbHqDlXZmjtLIGLSNcmTr@AIMwvn8Pehi4TFfKnNOYdH@hCwGyhuL97oX54nUD185wt8CuX/E2E/ALBLqYFzYPW@WgDYh/lLtHS/DsM3EENY4s9dYJbYiv3gcE4sG3BuO5JNR/48e3Dd93xFMm0Ozm@f1/gsVTkTJwjD9y2MuZuCVb2k0xQnAoTez1CvBMyC7xe8V0SBDPg10/wpAjWQh4wYiMfoas/J@8OECzEL11t0ATOIm4HEtUdwI@xIm2d8AVJepRwfSRfKbuFeDGWHO8cYSF0Kj6LTviQ8fKg8f4T6q/ugNtfDA7498PBZRfmjncPnwRtfyG0T8qbGp8Pi3dLIVgPB/thAVjeuf1KYKHsifmAeSd5F1pA6QFxJpYjwe7YxSm@vlN31PYADPa9OIMSAA2lNrBpidrXGqnwCLEwmLFAdHa@Xzo9ZTIfn0Bc4Hs4ZGgINoiwl/jVCnz3rGUTs9MCoSkYLAfCk@8ysXUtOPKxoDHPRN4cViFkkITAR8AsJi8yJK4nehYSIWg3PTFEH3OTubvxeZBbFoBvUU0oMK/IWAwLCijNLGaEdz6WG97ULfCW4LJxeE8@7ZjmfTdeSdQfhQGFN/8YLTwpMrv@XnL5OOenwwUs8@2ACtwASRpv5dTYGSTcg4CaNlmDC6rFr1LcNM8F7IiPO9zhlZqUsP/uBEWExIVwLguH2LoQjkXWuHy87Is5tPMQuwEDt3QKT75DGTx8Fk8uW@EKjY07PWWyCwIhEy/LeRKmCoheuc0H92sq436yEAjk4ba2TLkp@7ms4OysgJ2fH@gz3Nu8Ps0eppMCbrswKfXvJyneS0yk5ON8ZmF8T4C8nsms3gd7uhR@dPXvCpv3IdP80@v2YHw/BumOXJreB8o9fJ7w/ccEsAB1fKu832CmIoKoM6NPmSg7dUbh/EFe@LwQZAYVsdbbeDXQZKoxNpzK22zovEcKQ6cgd8oQasJBQXmruYP928XJIUO@N72lT0@PNzYMhHsEb38ZHK4L6S8JOeEx0Uk3s9@3KRg/ltR18PgYnUZaeGaODs3xDa28MOhJy2zhAjTFISO@rTbhTzFQIjSrqOFVYjipl5@e1VP1fLiEB4dHJbZCGsKaE1OQcl@OhVjOkmUvygCxXpqOwF6DjuJ95ubgB3lI@CABTXQoTyHcxO7NG2EEhOUyabgX2z4FS9WnK73p1g0blWkkZLqF9zFEpMnX0vFBbNaEeio/ER8y5/ZsBWIlZFWTKSq44TwuQpoEwWsT3UP9lIQa3sUGyQUXjxpJPZta35SodHbCS3TLm5XESr0gM@hzDbvrDvrXjcuW075qsg7rvakN66N3bxnLrDE84pt@zHUh6usFPN2qMLwrKcs2U0SwIoPbpNfxQmaMtIrgWe0oGw@/80uopg8eGivn8ATEFJWyla5PhXhSzit0y@uVgl1I5btlu5LHs3pevODF9biCDo@h8wTWwhfky14Fu9JfhmdbTfuK9Qe1EYySgrMfjM5@YP@OM1xizzbNl9M2Y@kRblbDMySabV4rwaXKSJkSyj/SIzrEo@Npb5ouxtmWhgU5AOwnQFh1h/QexaRHKW3Q8xzyEQmpSELsvfVeeuSfOkrRhAEEKVsVPztbBGccRsF1H@464ruhVZ1LYzoedYyFQJQxJnE7@UKW8QggZlQcvSpXJFczjXobM4HX572naGxri9@rfQveNEmHOzWMPh18SFXQiOsb8OnRYgImQYK5S8c3JCg@2nU0cBeagvLovAttdJdIEEQf3MbNbug4EsXfAgRwxD/iIpUmZjCFYAVyIj/qR3MHqM5tclyPqwh4CpJXyiMsLMLm6RXGwGnHN@EIkxVoAvdH14hOjit4RAlUnWx3ihGEj/HghBJahhY2F3FJVUpeRfx0xtGUUDTVj@YHDqHi0b3YwIksGP08M6H5jNie2elApjkuHo3RgUY6jivSjwfpu2VMsxJknvurd/zVCX@N@/NMjUNp0H@PA@XCgeTIzTjcLZPHwRJ30iowkk00qOm6BhLHOGx@UVhX85yqNQ5cDKqSU2XgsTXhoYZ8Xs2ofe6zNBEnIPDAv8z9BX2nRc0HuZwI@2QyffxKooJM2hsrtpJMUalmW51t3jkFPkhmMsOL2nl0rG8iO94oxZFJwU5AQMNpfGq2xcIYSlz3OQ61Gbm49UTWhDCxrUxngx86vNOwZrSREJYozTghbkjnCyEd8l4KgSCYSGjMb7lFP/JIRB6FwGKoJT9ZfmjxTgOHok038QIeY3yPL7@xT2bODxeZ7fmI53zIC88PI08iiJjukjwbTZPcBI99cEdRqAW9yDjt0TTE2UzieWiSN0jT5EemmzjLvRTwiTCj8DnFHbwHPgLT4wC6T77zqhA9b6VfJlekzw0QoXsdc8h2cBRh0GkqaeI8ume6nos6klCjJAzPe70OLiqSYHdNJ56Fbo50BldTxhBDy2iadIgbd3j4BJrE@XGIpLFjhHyN@z/GHu6g1eK3sjPUYQSsFSdULE@TduwRn6@ANrOa5qfCTTZw@aIoDOZb4UzwmuOth26Sx7vKNQlkMRekHIkXtcnbt5gux2MhqPcKurScJH1nYNUv9z7H5doNPbWqh1B2JVZ7U9rq2vigFCDJ90inQFzN6GuSFFr6rfOlXxUBJtgRdvRfAW2aV3h1rLQDPQYFdEE4dc3@ldnQJOnUDNZ4ES6SMi484rFpZ9Cv87kbkK3wylk87esm@GoXUBh@sX/mq8F1WgpLSLgmNV5MxrvjrQYi0D9Q0nRw8ZfWI/BUP8cHRuqaHiBlJcYms0RLyyIvJLt0cZ4JsGGI2@PF0kOABtvxrDrUDE1USR0AxVc5xonxC7JDOYH06h0DD/lqszKAp1/GGPAz4K8ULcqDJNbEPykPTBTMX0I3/JpJAvdzqK1Aczf7FnDfMYKpVihaKO9QwedPD8/Y2fHB@cud0xID88np8VeH@6V9tvsNLWHjOjipXGVPj4@AuwSL5XxR/Bgc5J0ziCmTh7Tz/BtW@vrktHR2xo5P2eGzk6NDgAbgT3eenx@WzhLs8Pne0Yt9WlwHCOz58Tk7Onx2eA7Bzo8TlKofTRrHY8cH7FnpdO8pWHd2D48Oz7@hFA8Oz59jYrhov8NOdk7PD/deHO2cspMXpyfHZyWGBZP2D8/2jnYOn5X2NUgf0mSlr0rPz9nZ052jo6mCHr98XjpltAcgVMrdEuRyZxeGqpgSlXP/8LS0d44FGpv2AHmQwaMEOzsp7R2iofR1CYqzc/pNQgA9K33nBQQCT7a/82zncyicpNyDFaiXvRenpWeYacDE2Yvds/PD8xfnJfb58fE@4fqsdPrV4V7pLM@ko@MzQtiLs1KC4V0@lDTAAGyBP5h3X5wdEt4On59Dn/HiBLczxKCSXwJiIJc7EHWfEIy7HLC0gKTj028QKuKBKiDBXj4tgfsp4pSwtYNYwA0Te@fhYJAgIPE8XEz2vPT50eHnped7JfQ@RjAvD89KMaiwwzMMcIj7Lb4B0oFEX1CpsZ4gX9wIxCr5lJug6mSHB2xn/6tDzLkIDRRwdiiohdC291TgHNpyUgpNllgOzg0Y3fAESvOu05WJWhLvzrzMnosJFBztHe@XQOLj@rPksfsL6HSyU4qPwn7Q0QSeYJ1QMNMwa4NW1bKbDh4VDaLx@Y2u20rg/QYxGJ2zC2nBFRdiGoUiRCLV6lc7VRjnnlWrscRDYk5k474YYpJ7UaiYKGPH4cobcH4nl@No35pAVPGxWMakbXi4vIAhOfIf841tRteMsWSyYYpoeAYfAfszRC5fFGnjQglwRjrKiBr/x0nSBATZLUENFFHxwWv1Ks6C4r5HCuS48LLfjy28bwg5AHPms1rJJI5hKRvWO9NPhidCmg3oJRQLWE1KUnNN87Kl/H/tPdl228aSz@ZXwKAtAhR37aagWLKtG2fi5E7sLB5JoUASpJhQJEKAFmlFc87Mw/zAfMB8yjzMp9wPmamtGw0ItJRlktx7knNigUAv1dXV1VXdtTTM7lDlrw2n077juqoOlY1BDRw67h3Vu8EwU72arU/A0qWyxGuPlNpNEoy@XRaUWTIvtRmNzMF/OjH9cRU0HLoBz0SpKzqKlrNJZ42ro71RxZIIFeg8QZOMIt@rw29efo3KXKO12c68/1i/57WF1oAY4BX2uxOqd0Z/Pj7jArDAKKQGoGQkgS7qdaOOsibRha@g4AUWooD2tFVfBLStA0pAjp37Y7NP3Ixno4UJPbDhv3xx@Oroy@Nj4JwI7ebu1s52u6CDZH1T4b9vsR@KW0oxwkLYxkFMo0/GKnkGcg@tFCNYdUL@RMD1OhbEcOBq0uglhmvQVhlpOyXkYzjcCNNfTNAAzw4QD7ZFcTQeFhS95q5MIQAnNVQXR3PpL0jC90FUIhoQU5XxkmZtgf9g23r5qyWuByQEJCRGUV@BckG5IL5nHytDUNJtKMwOFqnZio456JrGAZ10kXUs@s7SL6FtYxYjNlTE9UrTTjUBiIdZKCxlNTHhlf1XChci57wU6wvefCP0Bo9vJRwdBafzo/gwfg1oPNY18Tg6OXOWQZ9Iy2cHHkzR2pruad/Cw3xXgKK1J6fGOr6HsRoIlDM0GfSsTMNtHQ4k2yXZtz4tudY1UyrG4MB22kKx8hsoN2840kpbhQGR3yq4hMVt6VgljLUr3UdBFXmrw1EodKbQ9IvwQe3/jjjJaX8fFE5oPcGWEbLvXpikVhlXoL0SUkZX6j7BuMRIsGm@eps0c2NOzIUemFzSLNh7BlAgs7NUL95SkMKBk4MAJHI81zDXrzY4u/BBc3pqu1Idr0MmvcvQsWSvUFvFrXbPKiRzVdQFCv5wLZcPmozuPoWK1lO2kYtF4QIu1l1ajyOb21hvuip2R71Mhx56lRNpXrAhapacGrK01OKXMEnGLtPX0Y5AFL1ZeSNXtowolimGL7dabtuMbmkOWNAGfR4goLnjRgt8NsVNR0vk0ORvKIIdhrtGnRm3Igk31yWjy3GA7Tzu08kI5uWMr3C7GHPrFGYvac1yHpNRCHaSWBgmMQKR@bo1wDptslcaejqmRHrV0H854aDvAR9xqRI1DuYhEJqu8TXrlb9EmMf3G7eddL6OaD1I9/9yQqEHezHvlOE0Is0dekFN/3GUYESZ4cA@lGBJ7C9tRaOjq@poAX@or6qMXAVxBJ2BAkzmCf03KxUCii@ZviG17NOJPkR6whuZ91iJL/jEa1c/vcUnOWf2YFAAHLzB61QRgxBklJvwCu/2aiP4MDbc16Ng1jeP5WA37fshngCR@D2d0LarTq8kglzPj6NgCVJorz5a1KmNjvPJ9GLSeTYd@8PRdOSDroBRtBe8APFxSY8Y/3M4m15FlBWFPvSNQv1l8swRTDiiF/7WV2NtI8pTFAehY96Ix7Pl4QUHIqDDWzQzszTPpCCqYTbclq6zuZVUKqQ9HMniq@m2V9bdaOZV5stjbECW1UHmsp69FGNyfTHcG9u3CnQ/VMCAsWtVLd9dYROWgngPUEQ3ASmIFTC3bsDNQaB2sBLik/6i0qdwdjMM5RM8DzCvSOTQ64qP6RSB03@El9JPrOZuw6jKB/kLDGmHD8vV6G7t/M7QAwC/APzmRh615BECBfQdqHg@EcvMEpcSYNGpwyqoCYCSPJ2NhqDYjlONdhbZVtOfl6uwQUYmsDVLxLZbVIkr0gHhG/NqOR1gOZ2la/34o1WySi5FhsAd8TB2GqsJNrjLQpMWP94j8uENMqZn0rJjAL0KVT3AEubSyxhwmiBzFN67V0yrdd9ZyyDQyzNqMjIEOLbaL8nHQWQevFmZzoAZ2xnsibVBKYqnYeme2FvJO3KDfOXhuue6d5qaMrF5i/VWuU@o9Zb4uGwXsvBkiCaNMTJqAhpCFYqeNZlnkbjwOrjevM7yDjyswllioqM3FT3ffV77uCm@Q5tRtdHoJUWwY7zLtn5/0oGBd1ZzEGmTRfwOcYwOsozOkh@NpjJo0li6P4aI@gT2DD76gDnstw@4M@dnJVKz9lgqeqb6lIqXiPjEUN/oFgh8KRzg/T8GIuMrEs2kOKp58AQDu9JtUrPaxXi1@IEbRGeVoJqchfApYjJZGTqiePIDp4MGK03kRPB0YF6y6zDxGmEUx10OGOTSvbOsNs/a3NJCtwSyLJX6UEvKoxl@nnQW1MotVMASz0GFHtEt3nRx/1H90rFAOWiBa9NnsSVtVHAwrrUO0MA/5qfOAmXgpCupmVpR6YXQIdYAawHUkOE4YO0Jpb/RjCkeL9hlGYFoz68d/LMuNTAA9HZDYxurLPpLLOIKunm1uVb1gKskBMW/Ef2yFFnUJXUJGggYYqjvNaEFjJBJ0OPBNAV3MSkvBajMEVT0mrgs4SUF2ExMCnO@I1KlwOaWUaKRV2LPbKOa2wgIFvllEkBAZskvkrQCG10uLEaJnfzxJCVAIFa0zxiHqZBZSeNQzxwjEB4JWs1RTppWpSEUTB83t9zUR03f9HWvYXxtZL8CfjSEJ9Vm9utuI/U11W2rla6aqgn4cM1eUx8BFa4JsOYKv@w/cn4wo2drs0RDyUhJGWIKPEFV6gr1ttp3kbVPbr9KxlDtmb7HSv3qcFKOVHzvD8fytiRSfPuXD1bZRipAJLg8BT5T3hQO64MksNq40@OoUNFVody0B7xSaacD66s3x8epuKLdpTJ1uQxmW41GA2m4a4ZRV1a8eH4xmtbTpeuD@XhcD68@mX3VrRPrxzTV42j6RCnQAcwIrImoNp0NOZUAwgBFsXRVPCVR1Z8PBmbMfrwkw7mDWeOS4m5v0f4z0mYXX72hAx5qUvbXcxwgju/c0ovvymc5U1pRNyFQG41S39nqAgfQgy8GaAmsL0uoMeTLyp4Gti3XO7jGDQRTYdBkUSBc9zoxkLU/DsbjacX6ejob99EV/cFNtsLxsVmhwUXwkovcR@cRBTytWMG70dhwXMUiJqljc2pfUokJVIRxjLL@RTB8sQgd@@RbG3YVGPI6DnMdIx1XLHtouxJ2/B7NMh0C2PcqfemHTo/wlC0MO70s4OQJINpoVnJVn1QRl1KMCM7uLo1IzQe3RtEAYOguiQIqKjpNL41kRXGNXPt00RwgDhvchsCEQT3uVwN9mX4/rvguHgzuxxQpoDxP7G/OEOlEmlagLD/AJ8Zj/qcqLOvjTMQKlm8w7cNtvoMVOlihUHjc8364cg4PD61H4fq6dXh4BA/VqnV4dGg9xxdHR9Zz@H2Ev9e81tZWm3nuc/caXh6plzfWEbRBB5zrvYvZc/gJ3zx0TEJ7YZziR3XvUaX9qOPtH7Sj@snhEfqNw9Pf/u0//vbv/1k/lB//hT@O6MfJt7pQrVarP@pdP1q7aePvk@dnpUfdk0fhWWnYRipDdv/lLPLHvmHAWOsV7nDS6Y9H3VWOO9qCYxSRtSBa7Dnwj@eBBvbjj/x0GiePs@QRw3Im1f1xeOFTdYtaOPBKh6W1NXja90r/UqKzE3nv6/fv4b3lIi8nv31CLaaesQ5fP3v50ox8jVyfpPdBgGFaMEmiXJuMJtEIBnVeVDnnqidWrWadVa1zDR6aGnS4YBpEVjMZmH8VINXoyC6E7k9FbcCLUTr65hN5vie5jIYk36mjc86/5Yum8rj/hC91qI11YHhYvs3m0uJ6icMHcPEWxqueNLe3zqrFYrGgc3J1esTmqLeQ@tI5mtQ1Lt3BsCdQCEsGxs6p6REX0CAio1ikjE1rPc4s5kxQtSaNiRXuYsmQ5/G8iQZS0GyOT7jZnx9lLFT4KAuWFc3JEQBlg@V9r5QAAPLw2ifGZXHe2ygMeqPBUl@7Y1KEpHfYK9Frq2wNbjltWfasa8u4Hg6SBgEhKAVQuBhsNNsgI28KZUfE7XiM6jeIG7eJ6lziT1ubNMHaKCWcjpfDMXTmkDlPdAXcCTDvymSNJ8qbC3vgmt1ggHnXeUXzhCXmpAh3N8CjiEkPFMw@pigaY1goFvj4CpICIsJ6QAlHUpQN0BvBGU/YiGU6gEfY8NGRi9OxERmu45YqBIVKLSrHKsWZ8IFy6LpWyCURq/A7uQAm8qAjSNKHJdda6iowdKUmvt0XSgsxuxwq0hKe0pWVZNNa0RewIFVe4gUZXo4BUrBkjdJZAWtYWufjybkeP1@pRZgRj@7POOEcddPiO3LgWLob5bFN3bE5us2Hq5T8auLHgt5wGkWjLiArXqppoih8bL8@g1ZPSwXuTKgFL@oQwfiqHOoVZY5PkVKwCMlFnOF9gEe7E0UFqYJ4rYh3Ynw3XEzdFE@mkyqx3G4Qj3psxMe9P1S8OMRrWrLeJ8BWdwTKA19UqgmmHk5VgBu5o6SpTtohPKG9PK7/Cy16@4QzOeYVFi2@CwCQJg49O6cJkpIWNSVQA2mkCIxkgiwYfJAizHEwHMWpOhUJAsCWzzyKG4V6XOTnCLCJ3Qxm0VafVmXX2GfOBd/KPAAZr/oGjHbXFf/bPNpTg8FdjXMf6po8JHLp2r1NH5ofKXBMqGEFA/pw@VbSM0SbK@51FMcMo0n206RqJbPwwR6ocQGR@UWZfEyoAeEWWZxUTwAbrQw2gJ1mlkHChRup5g0CRuI2d3LiURn08nSxSHCLeSt6UZAiEdwUtFfJ9f93v6mp7M7QRRYWH5RCOoA9OjFz0KEcsk3mrsCrQAnqEp8NWONsjkHR2HxCdhSMojLiRWp0quHIdKWGLjNcJUkppBAd8POkZM5lpqoab1L7LF27WmKvomvlW@QYkk7oisuRfH3Am3lze0u1y05DdPVGv26Ud5M4B2mbCTU7gnLaXv0BogetMCjNj56cmzzSUDq84vJqzCJZgHCZapzaoisaKWdaouQgiW0VDufx9GX868v0FN5Y7vr0S8r4CXKBD2KwiAi@W5cneEQLWPfXUguQD4yAEbANlR8F8FwosOQhGqb9KhoeTRdOo3Jqn9qV5vaea5OerOWwYi8CzajYCzhgF2YNFN2TAgPSufa7gFn4rDvq94OJCgcKVaU3/akjzZ7gcf61ZncRJ1m1iYkHtsHLoypMIr0QXNNzOPOHlz49fjZ9M/OXL2ETop@fT3g@X2N7X8BmhGmB6MsXvEYP@yBq2DeoJyc0ca8hksuSD5JPLybRgIPBGeJCDgKCWwjgPvX4o/RgDTSY4@ezCy09074Jk3rOEkrEhrznfHFyXuCcs5eYFLXD74A2HSMprTzSp0ymZJER8IOyMTPecg0W9cd40xNMUvcQKnqtEB5nLuZaFWsMBNpQKteHhzJlm9xzDX10LopN3LvoXM7H8UhGdmtYalxYKZt@l9RJlTF5RQpeOjLM4s4YB7Z7MoJVmugyxKgSLIgSplox9EeFbho/HTsmQoOoKhx5orVJ9NG4aX9gbli6P1CqBgaGMC5slHKK4ywY6gbUbheSfdbSo36YUj4QDkAKglEOKfcxseYbc45xhjF0BTETPbm/hc7@96zk8hu6bUiwpPRS9H4FkYF5WKLrk2V7xWrIJbah1QKlcPLr6WUgmq2oE4byaiQu43iOv7vCeofmlpL@DFQpy2FTdnmYWmgp4VCZbBro1EIM7czmLNBYTWHElCSI5YTim894lpZu2DE6l22wUgIlGeaskK0kJj3SHPYGTdzaPCtajLj1yVXSm5aAqCjQVF8xVdndko1Nkl7jqV6ygylY0zKlKbJbyQaayKw5SrgmgzsRFdxGVPPnIYrhysMTf/nV0JRGQBpLN4VCHvlq1iGmWeZa114st/gSIe6hFoQzbeQIut0xxq1LAMs2h0njRbLfU8Jw2TocAltMy8JsYe0n71jrYQUyyngt64M4toqfzzCuaxGkqwL8jzF2gUtd4oFO6gQERNZ6QRciHyXEBuFbn0aI17xVL7oFsRmqFzlTTXOn6VIn9@gJnUB/gXjPbBCvYga3HLBwQyGRo2x1xInt7t2P9roVx9Kp8eUeSQNHTg6lmT2XwxCNye86pa4XJZqCY0Hzlmv9zANqOitp8R6E5zz1YuEBgMCSBoZ1g86o9roc8EYBDEMHheTj3MQMi/VDddD9Rzr/VjhWtgpCAVpAaCjpAOUzykLMEywSAjlT0gItPY5KgGrtypHbSyKqkbhIqE1RstrBm7JV5x4I6VmhXTqykiSes9g4Vcw9NVUnRFYxt5rlYJRLPM2gq6Oghwfh@pQqco3zYDl2qEPbkhQawGJnPd1kil2Zw1lbswQ2OrLOyBi5in4KUQxHChmnE2bOWdIFJoQvCfGypcAy0VJfmHv@wAWkRLI61/IFEWSviRySnNDUE7zPJxrz@dihqh/CDzlDTDNOLoQT4qg6/EgCTeGnIjSLzzuIlA70/n6o9CfNxH1JVVJHr6JF3ot3mrwXm3vPMqrjaQPuPvh31GNfU3JuTPYfq2w6AD/g/ZeOKeAfJlDyV4i1Iztw@yh2Jd31g0Svq0VxhzN3a/aLepyY3PX7sB0DsyXPpgroiTHZIFkGnpWBLTm5/6QNUynp3L2wQlAxEZSsZia1E73MIsXMUH@VZzxhaiCuxA@gOTIvIm9CvLqa9tg3HTYo/D4gz3TSa5usFqFCxBVP8Ke4@D0YcKS8gaxkHoFV7ki3MgaBhwbBMtbRzI/vJWIlV3JssK@T12fpMKoVrJc/XSS7j1xWvrdcVizTmXY5Ec/KxRBki42f2cZvK6clB7TQjq0ht3Gh0gE@qRyAYpigMVoYJ4f5wrXMK7efL/b9Kb78UTeG8h9efClr9PfSQkw5EWJ6uUJMUkBq9fDgjerp8sQeYNlOSEMui9jD/U3T/cG6Uf1Nc/vjZOBWUk4qT6lbfJ3TbXw1lRqaUKVDOn/M7Qh5La/pc1vW9rnl3F7QPN/JNrzx5zb8j70N1zUuMODlHTuNMfV/zv0/wtxjCMXxbmO30fnV7n31O9skLDtz32pZ9kOrefDRzunieeN0sbf5@Q/FuHjQqn89g79x8Yfi9m6RH@EBfm2oX@@KB8V9LLZ9U1zWPc@DR2nl8BhaOfhEt4mllvvwz8GWand7WTyoelT9x@LBNjw0Wy2A5HTxYu90sdvA/@32H0n8MG9XtPCxqtWQ4qrIhsB3gWIiT2r5NEqafGbsDi@RBJQ6nj4gxZ0fGq0SwGg8s2jtNkRWAQLi@A/vAkkBdRlg6i59PEUxTGKKo8EeFyr@g9jqcSVYAboLF/5QF7Tbi@iVxJxQ4SZQSkiAts4f17bx6vpcwlBoAHTgCRIz2ZQb1AuHOsYQW/j3oPGRrQNTPLElboVtWvzL3absiruyK/5v0QqX8cV00soJrF60nsF0xYH1XcSwRJNRGAYxS/zDYBLAloyH6aMpCjqY6a2HefHGo@/Z/O@JatzqUUOd76IO@@ZwQ7VwadmPnsLKGl2SVvQeVqV6xvux7U31Cxg35gxDPxnlXTMcxRfzLsXEfzNbvow/p0gUdYyrHXNUijrIct36pY@GAxRJPgISgxLADmbzSZ1yi4HAhr4yGP790v8eQMN8pjC0fgeK4WH/9w4lD42CkFxcFoOBTZl6gnH/dRD6M5@jpqHV/NwfBi8xMAxMRnRho/JUtD4j55rYjI6rlSXCOMjhkpKpyhGsiPdHJeX@Sai1LHQ3powxNvqpCxMi3m3XyGsCatnsWkBZqgfTaZyUZ69xXYF@pmtQTDCYJHYNwcvBZETAzXH86wqIdcuSFwRH8lM6TV5QRwTNzBphJgccVTCZXxLt6MyqJ80nZxI3zWsaGa7J4nX3iWQ1t21EKE6THDY3d/HLnG0v6V6yIKED9DhAsGZIoCBPyJxuCy9BU4iiafc7ivuDXAkWJNJfTX2TZU9m9PCIh92TYOgTr7jqjmIq0B9FVABr1ofvQXZnFFVSpNqdD6MarwVyrBhF0TzY2tndJIBox1dF@9NeqmirDi3P/NmyTsBdxJdjPYq9@MIaB@@CsVivENgUUZYXJdEZJtXy52Mya9l2iXQAlamRAhacvQq/e/7i@NPDNy@eV0BM2cLiEbkl6bKOgVz@vE7fB2OM1MBkhFV4@da625tM5E5UKT3FEzkG/amJ9nUTYNVAFNVwDxiFTsmjamJnwQ1bIartk2FFX4dfTWff68DFuNwQlDllO7AVctXKLxbRpSvCvopIgqnABlAHB6Y8t2djYDy3Cq3kFYAB4W6dGChyjPwTKdfef1it6jX1hJ6qwFir1QM@ZLGfjUegeJa@mE9S3LZEa8e3SsDk8PqfWdvDEvGFmt22LjzU49s9r9HWfnvvnLl7rbMiDxAKhxH3Znq0VPPnzMUzzQaEuGTlrFwm/@e/S277JgmiM3ZiF6P/W@89Fby4xkz9BadLdUpRDyYrhmrva3GwiJ9xtEkvbusK3Wl/KWnvn4FW3Xfem32EjnsNe/X6es/zNtxr6HIWYhTKEJhh8AZadNv4bpB6p13E6qenE8yBXEbXvW9effoxTDnaiQVRfPLtWflRvVIquW4bh@B75N/3/PNXf8VT/plbo9P@49n0UvAy83UnNZjty@ikcUbQV2wcWh1XIXDOYRDL6KOj5Rt/@BlIS07JBxSgWRI5xsGkjPZ98S9ro20SylyYH8TEkWenJ9d2r4celbqYBYM2n1XcRN47Z@i2Y/hzYXaxBV14rRa1HkMlD62aMlgfTWC3/vjNq0@90r5vYatezqoorXc1cQChEME4@OoQMyKlSAe4ClFVzN56RDDw33rJPkiPZb/uH5TaNzcr4fmUY7qC8FNKCLjvzCtCcTPv9pS2ZwkVLMPAwxe8tf3lxRu7AnUxBAu@nOD2tiSmxU6snuqDyQ05BW2By9dYxvM219boHVaZR57XajRcjIhyA61FmMIcmuWFNWvfzHyv72hE@uEoJ2FPq9aqsyNLVG9utxpbOx9NZ7BFeJgTfS0CFuKh1vJuFC/XQDYMPJX8Zw3kZNhNvYeb5d3PR0f//M3e6@3nTq/7SdOu2N9FZLY/C00AZv5VjcUi4LEzifdKQKDnYs@vh/730/pmv9EDybO50w92toLdxsZubyvY2Ovu7e31Bpu73f7ejr@z1evWMd44ValdjiYgJdlM/tjt4H7drhLMdluNvcGg2dze6W/tDfZajY2Nze7uVr@xuTnYbfobG9v91m53r/thqS2BpwAMVvFd3DuyHPjxauGucIu3S233/wA)

This answer is based on [mauke's code](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly) [golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153744/wait-what-language-is-this/188755#188755) by Ørjan Johansen.

Version adjusted for polyglot ([test it](https://tio.run/##bY69CsIwFEb3PMVFCm2H5gFK61boIEKxgyAi13JNgmka8kN9@ygquDie7wzfuaKXacIATVNBznPYwo1Ln9RsFxdgh0ZEFMR79HfSmo89U8YHNBPBQS5rMQCWqyRH4F8Il3azYRqw1WREkNlnRTajMq11yoRCZ4WNjrIx2u50ruvuYYeyTJy5aIScoDrul5FmqzHQ9/bd9PP/bHoC)):

```hs
import Language.Haskell.TH
instance Show(Q a)where show _=""
l a=length$ show a
main=print(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))
```

[Test all GHC extensions on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVVtT9tIEP6eXzGYSLWLbdkhQC/Gri6QHki0vOXU0@XSsLE3sdX1rlmvwRQi3cf7nfdHuLFDjqC4ifyys/PMPvPMznpK8vj5OSQKApjZLM5b22DdQ5TkZMpoDvdE8oTP81YP3qUFUwlLOIVQpCnl6l2LhrEAi4Pmdj70QPNAFnweh2CFWfYS79XlwNlwsf74QudEJXf0LFFUEpZvojoNqMuC5MllIRRtAHQbAJ/JPAlPMNk19zXMh18aMH3C5xdEIS@@sUrH2WtCJJzIh5@l0nH2GzCDUlEe0eiYzggKfFUw2oA8aED@mmUsCWv1jkVjXh2nKa8vRXpMwyRtoug21kh8FlykQmZxkqdXNFcyCVUi@CbcbdIewWciJAzliRqWbCrwdb1Ec1Ju96eAY6LI@gLojMpZlqXBNpzQ8hMTRK3qsxay08Th/I5K9MfaVMGxCTao7zbBrugU86za5/qBK1I2J9Ft2gsXIlezpDzPkJ8ScnPB/SZ9f@dJKKLN1V4guw2QIU0zRhTFjvhOGVuCnp@DJM2EVHAhKSsi6r0Mfzs5sk/PV6NKY/tTwUNkaB8Jnqs3M0utVqYhLZV9QiWNRLiyIUZJwexBGdKs2kariTNsuILMqf1Cyx6eeI/W5O7@69fL4ffh8E9rsR72Ohb3SyIYI/cSZEJ4SKHab0kExA/wjUR6zRGIcR8jD5gEgT/xUxRAPVgWHNa/VvA/GrsD@rD0nUmRnnJF51TCxO8DHmEerw4sWg3bUG6XrSCq9lzf7z8WvR46LzzqUymF1LZR9tlH7hc8JzN6QeVMyPT0vA0zoDfYt2F889eg8jwijD0urEACf83iNF8qCSsCNaXHitLLxMR3Ft4b3jqxgqnxxqavDSvB9MuVEo85DjGIpi28W3zKNoAe2X3jY9eL9D5MjMo0A6e6dWC/6839UQV8qm6HlqaNLWv0NIZW4LWC0ne8h23i58VUSYKt60xdPPC8Em14JHsxTP3pt9KTflagsh7D@jDK5ypuQ02EeCgPCoFxfjzp//7zt3Fo7flLm1fHemJUwcSe@OVrEXb9EbaS6eAfdzperoldaWJDm3j4mXiemfhpwvd9vA5w3MULfVycdw/GW1s60zUAzXRKx3ZNl7om6M5NEt0YphIDjqI6vV6lLW6neohPYux03jM9EkAOrXp3jdyxV@dFzBiyxIx1RF1RwpbuhgW773XW1iuf9rDIBqNxrzcos0uc0q3bj/s7e87OD8PwZr7@DQxP3zL8nN56tbQpSXide7aFJfczLL5C0Yp05MAWJowtYi0YydFYfS1HRRtGlou5OU/zQy3QxlinBbT@Aw).

Spaces after `$` are for TemplateHaskell, space in `- 3` is for NegativeLiterals.

Grass extension was changed to get more `w`s: [try it](https://tio.run/##dY@9CsMwDIT3PMWNCXQpXUL2QpfOnt1EmFDHKv6Jk6d3kxbS0LoHgu8kdEjKSudSusre4GFZWTk0RRRCrCXiuHLc6N0V23hvXrBo/L@epY@2pJ/cHWV8LM6TJ@N6NvAMRR4DW0LH4aZp5uBQLu9dpLuT1mi5o6pBRt8HxYhykBOOpwPaYC0Zr2cERx3qKqUn).

Haskell code got `Q`, Trigger jumps over it: `QTkTTZ`.

Comment: The space in `u$ [-1]` (last line of Haskell) seems to be unnecessary .

Comment: Same for the spaces in `0 !61` and `last$ 172`, at least when testing only the GHC extensions.

Comment: @Potato44 Thanks. Space before `!61` was added for Chip, but it is not needed now because there is empty line above it and space after `print$`.

Answer (score 3):

## 265. HTML+JavaScript (IE6), 12500 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]xx  >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4o'6o@ ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>onload=function(  ){document.body.style.display='block';document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:document.querySelectorAll?257:265}</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #a",_"[];l{t}8;rext7095?1&&1PLers$/  \nu2FAC0::FloatV$ f Cr=B51 16 4 6>E>83nt:k:2:~-<le._ngtbontgerminPrsharExu Uatafint 22w;ry ctorbody=>+pdisp se$t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g( ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance K Float;instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);l a=length$ show a;q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$ f 0$ f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a};g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPkB3ua97CaHZHffOyAaXQAKQF0CVWhUgQSazY6Z8casxlJ45fGsYyStdUey5ZXWjrDWsV7JYSkcIb06FH7SD2j5ZUOxofkHs@eczCoUQABkj0YRWySq8vNk5smTJ09@nawZbvsXv4jgw06czqjVcTzmma7HGn3ryuxrbHfEnhiWm0mvShKG2um3Bl3T9tycFGE6Y7Z5zQ7tutUAN@Y5l6ZtvTP74JdmrNd3Wn2jy7y24YHFglhs3@y87773WN3pdg274ULIVcZODPBsDuqXzKi5Xt@oe5Zjg9caYy/sjtGtNQwGIcx@r296BD7DAET9kuJM@qwz9szpuyYmXzdd10HHDca2zG7PGxXBkoUQRt9yjnaefz4VeZOxzw3IWa9jDqfyoqfYK8vsN6Zi6Dp7eX5wMO2aZl@qjs0O7uZPX2Uv@q7RMabhr7GdgeccetPuGbbTMm2DpbVNLT3tuc52@8adKBusbxqNptUxNcuuM5W1zU7P7DN0YU2nD1XmmZ1sKpuq7oxjanWMmx17ToEt@A8z@i0XPJ0rE4wm1ETPMhus2Xe6zLDda0hJ30yNwyPYzUlyqEMGgdDYNy7EbpjMta1ez/S4JxTX7JM3pMw6ln0pceo76TuNQd2yWxDOBLz2Bh6VyZXqEK3IeoKGNTSwCGGBB4MsnDldM1wXLhAv5NrtmXWradU5csyhZ9oulNfVmAV1d211OqxhdiDCGHo9wVyHDdyQU61jtLW6JiFyMRXWvewwi9V7Pca9oBiQpYNUlpld5xuLvQP/Tttlw16XuVYXvL2602yaJntn9toQnXUbUsORGDz13lTJAtuyCWFsE0q3d/I14M1DdNpNyFqD1ULhIB@UZyqxYTuAvj6zjS6nhnpvRKUHMEGMpuNo6N5wTNeOeuza6V@ymlk3sNiYmGu2msagAylaTawOoAPLZV0HvlCJNoNsQWQPcYGwMTFpZkEwGb96zR40TKxeB8kF6tqv5eu@AfTRd0U9elYXqMPyoi4zDddCjgVRXNNuEGX0Al7mQGnDlc6uLGh4gIpBn2C7Zp9In@AyLAWANAJaVa77lgcUgaXYYSem0WfnfdOMcTo13brRQyoNJwmJOZiChwXRiDC3tqKl44MoECiPoRk9IMj@6vl3vpAMphXYcjUPv4Is56XS8312s3yBZs4zgYh7fcWIscIH5iYvLkz4DfVastW/lQCqBFjpsKTT85KG2oMMqh5kMGmgEU3qVVrrdUIJs62pOgg1Gx6qAbUBTIC9TFDJ6oN@H7n7GKnGJRS649gtwCcUtj@weZWvp6AKgP4aboKZVybSAK8j55owfN4GCoF/CBriLLzDIYRClwNNUWDUT9d1OgMKBzFdD9sjYAWiIsTDJnvJmobVwSjgj6B4rvumC8SJcQZ2A2u@a9lmQ2N@Nojr9KEtXkFyBgAlB2gN3RBvoUxBYKgIh4qKXh9/83carRbA2anXnX5DkOtLIPY6dY0GZRY6N4YE69hGh7IF4RKYOo8OCVwZHatBXM6wRyIJygSleu0MOg1GDfXagibXNoDZmsAg6p7JidwZeJDHBOsal5wjWpxyoeBdowYVSwlQ2lRslT3Zg1qqQzMnmlG7A6@ZZWqvxKJu8rWynVO2ly5MyFxMi60sJ5OtPBCctkJOYIsuopyXOxNdhesZrmM1pN7Iazt2mql1JtcLTs@0legEjGgi2q9FYxpyaiWWtwp1rWnZDSW6BbRYhISjsXy9UC9buUp@Kno4SQBzjWCwuZpKPSYjq6FGcZXsgnChASd7qQpTyM9xq4hy9NZCzoiYabcr7hAh0QXp0kECAT6kuR3T7CkpTY8hm8BwM8uNHrNKOgVDFDhnVeLRSDQeLjpBgJJOFBQb67nlINvq9NoobwBSbLcHPLePtFs3gHpc7NQ8EOkSrEZ0TT0hcBbiiddmFLh2DRipT0fUJHmTw/gqMkoBYdyEJluy2Qg1ZGAC0JY99w437jgoHVCesOcB1mFjokYLqgYi84Ls8ILwlMhlskiXNjAUhFYzWVatWdAIsLkBTxc0HyobBF9N8zAAjTeSEO/pGiPs1bhoMG4w2KcZrAvsoT9idRN5DjAfk3comMiA2p8Lci9zmiylpjOZyTZ2p4l5/eSO@l1g0u@SC1sSFj7cmJDRsCaI2R3Dbg2MFvALx4YoRr1u9jzBqKAkrgesaLq/IUdVdJ6a25aWn0ynTZ2ILx6N00Amz2tPdIUGchchtqsgk6Hox8cCrGH1gS1BTz6VOgS4mkpcfoNBJjLwRp6TBV8CACIzh2Z94AFXAwK@blv1NtAs5s7mfJF3QtPJg1M4deDsajNIGjOjFx@nJS0ZOGE25oJQsUbvwoHOFUEVJxyo8sMOiyEbbncGYCfIInQEIVctaWhAe/fA7Dq2MwMoIDIAi0EmfXg9gCR2hkIxdFy@2EWNNZCUgyqCOgOuAS0f6K/teT03B/2E5bUHNQ0oJXneHx16xzYSS9LrjyzP4eZax6kBW3ahfSb9FJL1Qc0aThWI3II6/MaVrkAAa7qsAD332wFQnRJtusAwyX0PA4e8ZGLcBIK/ZQhIgTRAlNJ0iRUfAFM5G9l1RZ4gSjnBZGy7cgwMGDFAzRcovE1m8xtwms4lBgtnRktiqKTbr5NBDcmkCB6DU7akRxNFe2AepUeyDK@m0XFN@NqDTgetA5tzOYXLCjF2Iz16BKxNoeSsbq9j1S2vyn3Z48dCpmBLMMZDsamJMlMM4jwSg2kNGAqEEd0PD615zhkJu0oMCvLodiJhs993@jxdr913rhk5YDApjNQ9p4vcnb0igQslaBjWWjYO70VfSl2pMVOECPpUkpejUe0bx7KVm@jS0lI0Fy1Cj7m0tA2mLTRtoykOpm0yqWTCcBqaKEaCTOhbphjoVoneln3Iw1gFm8MQe/t3Vk8xyrncaiVhlHXxTeM3BniGHgNCq/gBONFYoYDGWEwuXkNBtVpzsvR72Oud1ftWTyDhC@PK4HaBhVVCA1Sc08eBQR6Fl8U46Rb6IF3AYKDeVvrRi3LqonJxc9GIX9xGExg7ljcKNSgUpKd0tVbfGYAYEiuv5VS9EouVV0H4qBWiqeiKomRVGMbBSCT2WTYWNzi2lagJvaFycREFpAr8lOvtPsEbJtKxWIAqyAcKPCBrK1HtJgvp12KVWDwKcWPRBAzdCtEoYKaOSHCp0NiWJhB0fPolR8xePC5R84ZRKf7udKfghoPeyegng3fvkHdxGLWAwjoDg0t5PREgeWj7YTX0nBq0@l61JkM@OpHG506Tj4r28FU6OpDMIdXW58cHpdMCJdM23EuQKdQWhk2CrAxY6Tc04AadQcOUZoUBtgGm@jgnOHeAibfqdaY6jIKpdZ6JUHdRZ3OgAa8hwdNhaqc7WQS3DfndmygDASF3irlIfqn7WeLBZ@YpSPIAOPbe2dHEFFn3EuQJVnc7KHyrfV4AsCZXuGODPsEYI8cOaYxmg4AJtAXyZSOYC7AdW0Ve6A/nnHBCfEIEQpAbSlsoSVgTYRBw0xrCkDiC8ylC9EeJFaX/PceGwampvSJuKDNg5DhbZWoz5f8TLkhpdXfcOkHSB2OvY9SB30@Cu5DZBQAEDpRMzvaJ5e8Anh4c0Dj@vjKCKFU3bMRfw6Jx6sBy24heGEtgL9BvAlZxkIqTO4S1Q1YHKbcFmDaHlsdHrdDCzzDKU8NVYjhO2uHjDKQylJExU/7MHQmwTh1G@CbIyujLp0tYyb6y@o6NSNZKABpYUR7rYAr4LPQCGe3sHKb35@N3FnDA2B1nPYTbMNRp5NZdaF2203FaDluBAEiamsYJ@9DGGU4Y5XhGD1qU9Y4QtNNyYKg/SYOmGcyZrq8G400DQyYpvPYN9AJsdqHHAeaU@ezwuyUQQ/RMKgX5920peoJChqBMlxEd62wcQKwCdJBusCa/a/bao/4EObmOmDfxaPKQGiafyTJAhIRciRb@jqKGGzl3gXbuezV806yyl2hMgJN34XH1ROknpBXebKCEkSlndPVRMQH0ToWP6xcZ10Vygm8FUwVqs@t4RvKlBiwaXxJKyKrFZDcZXYomVRXfMnmxdJElG@ZVErnUGPKwZNZnwh6aZj2Jvti5Md8wEz2@5xzUXMBj0wuKyb8@DoKY0@VvxePI2Cl3Qdo809DJn7cHpmTW2w6TL2CIES6ZDB1EG8bKKmAeBEAclwTRxIqQ5DkDGNY1zI7VtbxDmrPv2Dh20Yh5a8i1hO8e8JsxgBPLBIGcTziMOxmcVx/3UXaLhz8FTk5QYYivcZT2zUZyZQztmeP0YVzpMp3mFNIB6rvCI@m4vYbmDQEAj1Wi/t31@/nnx/ul6snO@dNCcuD2kx2rBjyiYVa7MJjtQHOY82DecIawBLRj2U7XghL5IN9ddk4dx@PCAy4cPOyJYEQfxtF@9ehw93Tn9GuROerRre6gY2Aec8tTAQIYZxRmIZi6U3NAtrAHcyGBcHG8e3zkQ/nixdHhTnW/dHJ8HgLzzaBjGfow2btszSvQFxiE6VqKo/6405hc0aFh6sQsgmA2OObKMxibMlWFt4puPFEclWnogSIydo@qirPABs5z91laT21uNmpGNmuuN@praxtNo9lorKX1bKaZzaQzKXhtrG@a7D0FV1VzSDM3YOKzIjiBhGlA5umja2u@hAND0TpILKOZ@Qp8F2SunsmYG2ubxmZ9c3PTSG80Vo10dsM01zeaa6mUua6nmrWsnl1dmLlQNlC0Gtu6NAMErQ4nC8gTmJ8Cn4nmwDMPst41a6TT6fV6prm5mm5kUmuN2mYqk23U9A2jtmmmmmurelpv1NN6zo@LM6rAJdpQYShV2iCa@l6qDp4xye9Mw1VMq4z@MrRgOMuryGJ6/jIyDhyExxp6DMQiMk7NCvcMuvtLyDhFI9zX0b2LC8hjSZasgaMImKWAuI6s9Wu@4yY6BivIE2urwCoF/5zlPz@SgHyjp24R@DWuQYfKd6Pr5H7lNZsTzmlyvlSxK@uMnVfJma9AT679isLe8ZoZOIC3RvD4yvVMeHe8ZgYO4GU4PFzxng1uymdW0ADYOgHDFfKZsKY8ZgQMIG0QpPCq@tgvS37zltRFWjO950YKYG8SbL5aXv2Gr1ZUxWI5UjNvIOcgiR05ID8fWThv35xoMVIwAr@QZH8aYXIiaeyTHi@TMPVq9vqOHAbEmYFlXzo0cA5M1ZSmZxBKAKJ72bkbswlDDXpNBL2Tqbs@vP/q1pr0mhEAO93pmTnyoGlP0fVDV2skT@mDE6CzcjA5lTuRfM1sDmAUlKxZNprvCaZuZilks1az5gUFTODmA/87I1iOnQ5gJJrW1jTdH/bi0gnwbD4Pe354TAFrBg3iJuf/2QTyvUHfg1ji@1@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@YJT93Apdw6hPYDL8VVUXKcOUY7mzENa3bnG31zRou1cmfw9u6N7NzNXD@BYaodIwqrP7FEa9fsoFbcD0Ws2Hi9n5surd2a6T7YBf4ojPEB7IF27Vsdx2Rm9F6Gl1Ydo/D2bosMYtAxbpfWgsHl2NJGpHtPELOucejU6Laeznm0lDXjNrfxBv4l9gvg@lPsF3EvX7@devnzk2Lr4zmX7l8n@5X11R0sTfVy0DxkX9MCzWJhYlJxfQBhJ4E6c2YU7SGUpppbk4@V5FdCvt6@Nkf/9JXqWedj1e5beiORtEP8wwmYWDF6fy@C/TGpri1NrPIw93QG7cV8hQpV72TGhI6P3nSpl6ZT@iTH0VOrhzKrZGZgDcyavOq59Y@L@9gWjkIdnKiWKsSxmO3FGCOc6g1DvxPjxQbnGPhxtCxmM0bGgkd8r6czkdz2Q0Xs45D4Bwwka7kZs2YPeROVOjOLs08WYa/f8lu00JjKJPp/KkbL3y1MTgrxr0m/h4IoPBnFtq7CWSqWEfBOav56wLBp0rQZxv7H4eyJhchmnPA6LsyH9kHF2GuOpVKh669JVcVLzYdwpPW9GgAJvbiZtyza9Eb7nVcksbltznM6nVCEw3YaF8htIpbjwc19V3pGNxG4wNp77cHHmpNacN@vBOyQxOgXs4cB7ETWEp14fVM0qLllDK21NWRfPA4Umcu9LBbp5mlziWyc68wVPMaOia1ltY2GL5OKsUzM7Bv8M19cWwdvUVhfCC0QWISfT2hauh/EVsPGKamSKb/VGgCyrAYOcttk1ybpgdGA0vhm4/mduoKGDvxneGq03zovXs4BR2PieWG0LiVKeY8OwzDP6LRPHNR1cFReu85izP6s@E7mHXaNl8nNVi7jneKoDtw7z0eDYOHvSI8d3ndUhGt/6sZgUoDFdmiPX/84E@GxUh/ocdO@fqptq93XaqHRfQ9eSMxcT7pEV7bbTtttmm@8ECmzzmgdQpMdPxC0qBOS/1a4z4k/hXUphzHacTuchmEX@yLml4zRn5qmE57QaEPWT4I6MGniIz71TgNDXE4Ko05/XbtrmALos1/GcnqmSbV7QDk4W8fc8Luov7vyys1ALZwgAI/73l4V/79i0ZTher0efaq8zcOlFUVU6XjerKg8omYdQheXxbUecbs2WU6u3rfuyVDMNz7Yuk/6MELcuHNn2QliwmLqPzlrHAuT1RxpSQyHsf4afw3lVKiaXeLcVGGbXcY7tDfr9EWLCcxzmdpzrMX@Y3D8RTOPy1Qc0zMuBWBmc4U3SAO6s83eQLVgCEQuJcwmMhHAUuFUzBQKLPndGaWJ7Z6h1rK7y1zy5aKr8lKnQ@u2nTImKbQ80OWiFZm7BfYJ@JhajZ3ZWdnvQcu@yOz5h3wARC18za3qnhWeapyqaVyr0QIYtPvPwne4kcfs2fKtQcwNz4epKZuHyCoXTO6rhWPCpwgfqcDB32qxj9Vz@ZmozPVNguLuEfDfUaPawWdRPw2zytRA03SfpdZ0@HiICkUKt9023jlPpyJG5/MS5j@20gDOrHTYO7IedWYS7q9Yzqz/o8dSvnpstA7dXHlm407IzgyoA6vTi9X1AvzMwXOs7A8czZ8KbXsC@D9wzo2XVn05g3gfmY1TsweOfCbJHp7vIv25bLp3f8A0L5pyQyDjZIp1VQd6fNVqbmq4PDkYvnlYJCUpi7zdTD5m/Rzww4IIB@hsz05o1E@/0aNw4ItOiSXjLo5lZ8Z1JVbM3ASxK/nrQ7Q1c8ZmdOu3TCU9Rdy/J3b22gC2qb4Ebs7bR8WZPY4dmZkHmEp3k2DhPCv@u1XFa7LvZFAMRDTptFMpnENwudNcnhgctwp5BwJT2AxdKcdJD7fOCvQWaMFeZatmWt3iCx/MMGCP5XywM72zwFGLyCN/ak0@FoJ7PxsjRQgkG@vZRvYOH4j91JMDZLlDhGR1aR2Nwbj5M9yIZc08A9HsX27wOj9cWLvrksEt17IGn4i7/RX3K@sI@JceG2fUQaTDlO6VnL2JhCqHtr/fJoSYMBAduZzQ2zd14MEV4lg3C2nxePBnaH03sm6TS4JQ2at4TZ6eHp6eI5e87s0Y8JyPofR48ZIIOZNDdN@u48nhv2s@dZyC6QVfWA6bbPTVxy8AUL5kdEaMdOXWjA/hp3JvMGYGd0VeMB9dGz6xB/XbGptmy2CzA@4ZnzJGdaOKQRoCB6V5asTo1s/8NzQiGzPMGtZMZemoOaRgyn2B4K1S9ep0L3DgtN9FGptd23J7j2PxNTDgFH/3ZYmYD3QO9Hr7iruH@5Yneb@YgbbK0x1d8u4nZ4Af35hW3b9acDn9jEeawA9vimwuMvmW6ySPLHgzJjakgu80e5vBtvCltA6c53DY0tmsLxtjB7l7crMa3CrtTIykQia8Ml5b8Z49pJnYSP3xXUdvo1x1cOxOGT1w5Cx0Ju4ePB1ul@daEGlTKEBiaUR/4egXuyWqnW@vSa@6YJFTTp2YNj9zV6PyoZwxnCZGTR8eE49ThLZ@lYcNfZ8oJjHpi93dk00O2SYxbPXoRQ7@eSSZ@cs8ts/7OiN3DS4NWRHPJSYNGtDMb0uQmOBBzOqbqtXGPZdLz5jGM59bloPGAtS5/AWXQNXHNenLlZi5ROW6bKMKZvUofMNy@KbZu4y5BaPq@GbmuujOXZBE8/B/vfpGEjrm6voYn@AdDtQXs7P59AZD5Qd8Wn4eQ3Ynjek1reNxDNU5Ofx5/wWJlIAp8eHNA08q8QkB92oMOn@9ohXZ0dRs0vgNpsOmAqUMs3DNV075SScXR0F@u7Bu@Hpm5dTi9OVS/Z3fotRusB4KH2nPpm@y5J4dHx@daz9UXzBzihr@B1cHVPcqK7wYFJNP8Keoz2qu2WN7cP94tHe0wpQFMxrFj94QWC6K9tlEzPSNpzB3noK/pzRb6np4/O4qPDy0zZa/dd7pmLOy9d3aWgIywL85meodjHwB1N53h3OiHJV2PzSC/FzYtB85jeTNSmgfp3ITRKhDTU35@9l6Bqe70zMb5qGe@hN4Q2a77wOTXKXVxSIn0KQWaN9yEOD4HblZfHNF3NV85mDhrSF2Hf@oFHI16fYCzXND8NEYBFcWIx2MxScR66lyzLmoewkguHZm9tHp5lvKNSC1tkA4oPCoNUNiywbYKLJ1OsVgsz/VvAGlB@xiYeda0fNA7rmu1bMiCnwNSnYRqVbhWJpfBEMTz4ZbLbPlmmEvl9FtWYHJOZpUKzzE@lEhp2CO9R6c8ennZqBSWo6oaXY5e2DmWigbBzQ4MvWcGNybCQmbxIzIc4JfrRHNIoVmAzTxXGwNdIqpkaht2o2MyQWNQ/j5XfsI165zjVuq//MOG0FRFGtm6lmt0ACGobA7Ive1cb/N0fXT1egZqukIY122cJsfU1b0dBkN4r97mCqqgul4cnGeF2huh2Q4sJ3wiNMgFpxxcjcUjvB4nDJ6b4DimSDiI5RcKxoaDrg3CWMNruxo7s@h07qA/Pm8j9P3ZXh@XXBoJdsgaJu5apUPXtMLYcZxLOoiFOfnLP@TKfujotTgS6ydPSr5CKeIJa5007NTrzgBy7QN5Z/YdEURBJBt1b4Dr@aRjjtxjeCCZtBABtau@Dh5Khivi2ds5Y2qJRVF7HerMyFtNZXnn9POX5VSl8IF1k@Z//V4ydiMQJ3@mbq67coL5QfK3SFhh7wx4j32jTF4eyjzB4Fy6JUZ/17w@UPMeJzI8mu7TmOP0/GaDwwlSGxZQo1DHoaCZ6tlXxtMlFWxEsOY1KeOhA5A29m@kAtCFBgbWGIHmra6wrAz4ErN65rEMJIgKjQwwcaVtdFIbFctglOUhe8@oD4LxhJ5JgY0jsoO6jLqFXf9Mw2r4rEly36wNaL/1VVpLZwpUnOVqYatIJpBXHNQpVn59MUyn1IvhRqkCIySB1IuL4Wep9FeAdacPsR4nseWVnu/fLGvF1Pv3rjFisnwbzfOzMcAmlm9ODk9KZ@c75y/OoBZufdZ2wE/I@bwGqYgOvbadDmlrA7zgUOUT@E9gG7NB1Acai0nh44kUVOBaVuVlbgyxponY90SfFd81Q/53Awie1rSYFPQMQAUGERtiDQs/6KHOOSbiCr1ZRGUW9h/YgALE4AmkGbyUUCWzAiBLBWQ9EFVsfmG3udtDMHYvlMVo254ZBDEWpFcO/HkRZ6Lg9ldS7p7hun//cnMoi8tNYRaUG4IGrn6cg53DoxenpclofidPXLewmRHncjlzxpbGhzu@ojBShyEi4hJ9QWYyReBW0ZlxdaWmd21CsQRzrHd5ZKJQyr8sjQkTMFNAjbkVIYUoCuUA5RsURKaPDcNYJJRFv48OgbvhRQyYwIEcgPYzrskCcoQ0v2r4@MVAqAJdftM7ISYu@HXUDYs/Cb/FYdGwjx64vM3N6aqCXsdl8B/qlXxTusKGTHRneoWpLA2/jmm3oMB@2Fie91FsmSNCXuZ5l4P8osZOyFPjG4NWxeg4jDhuC710x@i5vjAYYc8dz8yxtwOHVHr4zCSQL0hZrMEV7FLVcrWxpCoEZHIYgvj9FsE7PDgroHTGRTPi72GaG9jYUUEgrutWHLr3@qgTmp@G5konOcodod/Q7yppZskV@swCKcFlV5ZrgYBOldBEGacDnBJLIwqO@pJJmQvb6bggkzSg@wYJxcOuFoQTjc5o8oOaqs3kCNCkFoiMCSZLGNYt3NV3B13pNY4Y3vDIyxSOILshmNGtJVUFzLUs21eOnENtyTSpkmNef4BbMIvRO1H8LOTIpLa9bicUcIbmzwsz@fE3f4dr@7zwwPwjYR6mdsH268LWBPNv@D66DrZ/FtjSYPsxt71OYpXdVXE4zmegrWLuqVYgzifynYIhY/DVRFOBgirH6n55eMLcOmofxgrtwrhvXFfIZvxxCrO6QBlXVNEYnKcwrscxHKX8EugEiAuIBGUcFGsoPbNfUVDbXS6ZxIzjYplGe2HNId@fQsrv3g5Q6StIYsn1zPqanoRMqlc@QNLH08KjeRxgLJYDxihdWb3Cm1qdbW1tMdmtGx2zsJ7nBJJcNl6vym@CjC5DWImPFsoM4kCUcQzwK4poyrIR12MYFXuzqB5FxtZwOL2BSKiQAYLE0Nn2NXiAzOkIVAEx2@bQI7Fp5I@CgGvbTkjbsw9IBUAcNqomnW6T4@N2OMMbaqVauBrkVxiMpjhy8iyKLb9mF96FXREqahlQ389m0K8N5n8yQ28tpyzUUHRXYaoyre4US8OenNkOTpQfQG6Zkk6mV5P6eixEobIABfnF9v4eQEILB45RN61vnJ67s1c6/OL45OyO4iwKGZ0OFmXR4lb8QtUS5UpgiAb5nkTq7kHy7NnugY/KcK7GU9UYYrz3eDqbs1Kbzumc1F/xk4130yaPOwnpqYcCpnku9YD28N@FPvZNhgLu8YNVd1JVYje35cpW8cKO3En@/SxlyBFtBYkLTBcuqUKOTmcTsxhcfHCOFx@4mn9sX8cz@3iY03MuxxoAhEPIgwf3oQAHkLSkH2oe84QMHPMZoLGqmjS/ecEl1sdniUhFbZCjUMhz/44GbFpjzYpCpWDbcNsdqyZBB95ANZtcIZCv8SZQJaS5vY7lKTGJpkAKKAYBE1PETQ3D3FCjFXaFFCITrARbpKXQhxeToBEAvOjJwG2zE6cXmtvaN33TKUgjbH/Al19N9sWgC@Ga9Dk1kcWaIJ@oEBkQFQ2yykfV0LKEksJhHBVBQnplVFUoCq51GxllGNPa5rBhtYCBK7EEtPTPdBCrAjUKWGhSXGhHgcdxDH@OB9rCKP0kXZXDMXCjbGiW3TCHCipfylVAPkX36PWrq2hMvkMDpDBzz1exN6U502@IhidaxFjr5FRj2wyuZ5hSbbq5iQqsUCMEVAukeOb1j8AI/ZPS7Bo9pgxIpavLNEZW5UKxE67XjzG1yLXC2Cwep1E1fMgDpGYM2iQTEQ5TcB5SSRagdtDVtRv4eWf1WFnXtAqYKZEYW8YZtT3oynEuKibBKAmi5AhsAeuW5TBHnHo1TnkQB/0l0jHHUK/pDG/SREoTuQ7igkrNio9DurnGLZBjdXMzJ2pjktVsMiCLu1xeSwLYGSzEl1IBv@KAP2ANNfXjlQ64vgNs4cmXpm2bgCCgma4BfbAxACLrxxL@1SyJsWZ3SiHCs/hUaAyAjE5qfC9Fbzq4CWA5mafJmfwt9KlvLrBTbYpudZT8H5NaMn@jLHcKoyQIOrGistwu6PHVlXh82V5Rlm3s6h8/xjmd22WQJKoaDJGGEEhd7sTyQM8geRSW7fyysaUsNwrpFYoBVhik3UCED25Su1k2bpPLj6GnToBLnzdeZdklpaEpTdNvIX/YQpaTCaCZG9SxSPeyYPLLVjyOedCWq5iBD8mLszjx7IuzJE0f5YU0mmx1RXOb4qpBTdy5lYYjUDiLigbGnkbGLg5qVP3AY33vq7P85sgePOEv8Swco@23phsW/@VJn4czFsHvoqTPjato5VpbAYFDBZCI1oQRiwEz@cUvIvo6k5Xl7fXVzlU8mknl4aXnN1iGfbZ8kV6LsMgTw/BgyJ5cubnYz7aumNlMr79V1bLV1N5WTi5PTr4ajmIXSjSyd/xa1tcg6AbbpN9Dnw2WnvOwT3sikZWkFEmu6I83ksk3b96AyItPuagV/SBaJVZWo5WysiEcusWNjZXEenYlcfokWoW8QHFjSjodO2OWlWQXVs9tNODntOmWJCXCH7a9jemBAf6ZcOsOm2Qc7pit1qBkjLi7FRng58ATcZ9999WrV2h4RQ97dyriRzhEAS6SqxqZCGUynUr/5Z8u3SZuTqpbf/n9btJcws8xfn50@wzNZ3rms6Wlz3Z319YSgDhuPvnuydc7Oztr@4nMSTmzvaamlrb@4s@XltLprXRyqeK6eiVavvxKTqfWZO0vfz9aPTn5juti3eGzynQw4jsLP51lMuySvYPnssnwn8zvGiGzgeZa8x12kCAsF4jZRKOZ1ejZ6yjWz7uIruuREf1VqWhLTC9ub/y3nxy/jXiRYjr5qg9fL/I2sp6NcCMYwLbq264ixcgWBlu/jYyShUIBjBv/7d9D/OIXAAd9RlvwKmZ8WOujSFEtUJT3keI6GPR0GtL9f773PSlSHEImisXDA5YuplcEmejZx/pjMtleGwSMi4ieXTt@QlbLfHKczqS30GybeLtMG4ajyGR0PX3BROXpogqxuDq@uQNrgxnr1IkwP@i4zplPUexVhOgDCIRohJuFA5ENd3g1He7VhWGsbMTX0k/s/KvQM2H51T@neInX@tKTN/vJ5FYR@nl8crknF1XRyJJsIys7zhOc@suzI@Gax9fQUVUHgsPvghxVfAT6ItlCospR5Lcx34eNbSzsFBGYZEFz@iXClfD5q//rr376Vz@hv5/S7z9LEX@Ljlq@qhT9B@hHLvblmwthtZ@xZ/yxbfiHn29FF3QAky1mJiPBUyzii/6FjUz0nXITPsXAQiHGUeaGYz6/onSlyIdkkuWwlq6KxXB54EkGVioGzzkZnoVKNy6fKM82PEvwR//wBFZ8L5GLcKYgd58lVlzwLO4ApEg5Uq5UhkM2AWQhRHxONSQ6Tdiq4S7lSoqowKXi8VMgUiZoG56L@D3PC/hpWlXYktoYakSK/MqfosQiN/BU4urtbVl7Hc/nxT9Id/nAhg83QdYqt6q69boYj5cpi@WiyOuWGl1zouvOE1Yp8gLQW6u@3gLw8a3yVsHZo59WRXypldfF8tYkDAJTKT55EkfUPgEAxeUKg3EF1Mbt1m3xtrx1e7u1Bf9b9L4VX3C93brzT5/xMyfM2L@C9X9RThYvkqJRFitg14CmwUVLXiBxwxfClctS5AYph5UrpPiuoJb19UxFZdRAVoB5JXP6Sno1mRl@tl5KAw9wMXhalpMraHiPfSVIO5tSBMcNm3z4sEkObz5@@3/g7@Ljt/8WrJA1vGGQfGtv8e/oHf699fDvvI5/p2/xj52/w79TD/@e1fDvxMW/87f4t1PDPylSYAxkt@XtVCd1ldIv9UswWCwFonM71dYb0O2wlMlSo9SIpbqO3gCTCX8pMFmpJku1WMpO2boOnmDwWMpDUxM@LfhrApQ@/FmpFAJPXTFIpYOdGWmPpu/7KotdSGUWfWOCwKXpWkpbt6qVzHrvbTlayUeSFxdJLoWy9FqetIXf3jJWrZae71erSWwJF8@c4/H/8XE3bF343z12nh07XQf@j4@Pn10AMyvGn8TVJ/AUivEt8dmOFPPbFzkVqdin50hya/uiuKqieT0OJJpGt/gnPmOI8C0uXUgwSn/16jpPPW7@@ip/nSdDYOWGqggggnEDxMqLnhpcIN7FqyT1rtfwXBFcsqHxGjx9EzckX11foCwJI4fgH9ARtv4K/q3/f/0/e8GUciUGjeDmdkuhJ4Z/sdjN7c2teBdjiiIsyhb8oQPYMcrNbRGNFOgGTGUlVond3nI3eCuxLQ6wiGlsFSnyOCCwjUiQJqXLX8qv9otp8@ciCiITjKkVsSB4cTFMpWL5GrgEqwLGe1pbiuVp181yDdcDYRypxyhEZi2f11e4Ob2WzufXhGUjm89nhXlZUTbvPsXUtr6@nkuvrcVi@XxKhIURY943AgjTNep5bOT5SAwzy1u@ksJ5SbonJCrn5MePFXGzzHavF3v8WN9MvX8fOFWrDatfraL76vv3clXGDTqFzQzYU9n374HpRGNOX3nu8KVhRdXZZ@kipbDp9KFUG@DN9GR6nGbbcA3P6yvvrF5Cxt2hrhwj3d6plNO/iP78x9///kW0gFs2yHVNRwCYCstsba2vFYvra2Bez0LB5WW@B0hpxTf12O1yUubFZfJyNCK89OxGjFxvo@jPIltsuwgN1cWH3dxGqP7YWiam1EZm7AZcfDd9c5M7srV1JRvfFH@FpRgrrjDxVy6XV@NrKxsrTyoo69x5kKnmb4xCNJmM3hZujBzOX93m6@IOCTy3ZTx@vLoJyMym8hdStbq/c75TxesncXUeukKGjsShJVx57fWjZZpszGxWyliwykU0mss/oWrXsxkWieZFODUK3J5lN6n8EdeVrCYe4BwS1KnfSqTH9I1V6GOhi5V6tFFqI8UauNbcZ06zuQSOUHeshtsCXLPT8e/duHb6nca11TCXpMjJ0c5e6TyR3oIeO32ws5dIn73YjehozYzt6M0iq@hwWtrZP34BMU6OSjtnpc8PX5ZenIC7K33zzjBNwxyY5nV1MLh@i3czmFWzB67jp2rWLdf45hujRw@MWDhz/vizH3782f/08fd@/PH3fvjx9376829/@kP4/SH8fsy/P/53mxl8//zbf/YHH3/398DxP8PvP8HvT3/@7W99j//I/mfw@y8htz8Tv1A4/pMA1q///Nuf/P7Pv/2N34bfvxS/3777@80/nf376Q/m/zDeT/5gcZgf/3v4/RGH5Yf98e9yN/zeCf@7PNxv/PbHf/Ef@P9fiD80/t7Hf/Fn@BKWf/rbf/FfPn7/P6bT2b/4Nx9/@OOPP/jJxx98/@MPfvTxB/84/fG3/o2eCr/@4ONP//i//8kf/fc/@V/o/w/p/UcP@f/42//0r//Pv/6///pPxO9P4fcfwPSnf/0fgVL/9o9/hv8/@eO//U8/w////V/97R//r3/76/@aDL/DDf/vv/x3/P033//h3/zgn//N97@d8/7hwve3D3D/9h/A5eH5fAich5TrU12@/aXy8/fBxjgVoAG6A4OlQYbdHZk0c/HZMCd9xiLFFXyAJZez6Wx8BcTPlc1N4MsVct/CIEyCdvrTf/Lxt34NyP9fADCw/c9gg39uAa8fkYV99dWEJ4vTbIga/@or9BTjx6/CoX4EDu@TIIynnryHEF@RN39YEAzS/d8oGIRjIpgfbjIDFAY3e3L3n3/7z3@fPIK46PxrEyBTvnM49DIGf@8X9UfY7selCYf@EbKOjz/73sff/8cff/Y7H3/269g1qGubiZ0E9OyLp3shYOYB4TDg@kPCQUAdx48w3l@S0mBY2sIpSkmPv3kDuV8CE4y4VqTMKtgkvUhmHc0QMQ42AjIcxvEN/9LaJkMLuAzJFb4sDl67cbwbPS4NC@BHQfFSdYbGYhachjjPUAC4GInHSVSzMJZhw12CAjEL8VNWXSkMecQ4OhQJApKNhE6nsp6W49nCPiRYGO4zhIXA49Ib@L4pFLOFYRHBfaAsAIz4LiQJofDO9viw@AHsBYIJ4aXh/gfISrYQjxez4FLAQsYptUSV0tQzVDgqe5xRudGdMdx0uf0EmoysZ2U@DwKoZCI0vuPj0BgQgoP/RXxFFIf@fSP9VjA@1NOQ8MPduP82OlN8EQDgqiru1YOfqmJunoD3kIOKU7LwiXMIgLk4CVE@SHAgeSUuxal@42SB9CEPn/ZsIatAcFic5eVlMG0V5VW5egxDSBir9S9zrmf0cS2R5Mgck9c3ZXTGjU98S@fyCY01V/ZX4K3Df2mJtjFTWfIr0nIUpzCiPGuQlhpfddacCC@GX0ayrVAR4hSQfQY@@HvyBMyAI/qO3XCigf7j0uuIxCJU99BYEvwNH61A7qGmRA6vC1J8bMeJRxFD0xJaIiG@Gn3JQRMGjXzFV1smgZHxYQ@tWDN9fY3FJIVuH4thDdVNEsakZ25r1xnCkCMhywl9HVehYmLO5jyXxtYqlXIpeH/t5HKFD/rahgRfsg/wFjRxHxfQDd4Fr21tYf0Xb1SaWEIjiKzrUrEoFuCZLhXPSucQ/PyY6emUxmC4crO2kV7LrGXSq@vrmY20vra@ubaeya4CZ11PZdJpfXNtbTO7uXEbYOsJMKdEbqWW2Sr@ozvP//CPZj2zXfGRil@xoUZz6bdSsVPgG0GXcTFevkjJeZrlIlwul1MJ/EuvrsIb8pnQMxuVpaXOjYrFvqDdhze43QGyKt2o2PE9godJjyT2CJzggTRwOZKJDSSHx3mxWQAvM@UbBmQ9A4QM9XABlMzBQY3e3NyEflJk6bvf9VixCMMO9fBAikAbbDN/eVy1GlpboztIG4O@Sb4txvYPXx6eHR4/1/YPz2Ac8DVLr6Y0KXJ7e9sMFnXIarLj42MJmR@M71Z1jH9bZ4PBgHxrYL8dGlIv/ORDZimdVtOr6qqu6qv4f48hjf8PD5@G/zS@IdZqWuLnFzt4lMefONuUtrg2jqJj47ntgn@/qgJYvfHvnddqTmOkud4IBnkNy@11jFEhWus49ctofjKMhVft4CG0gjfqmXRdCJ0JPOfK8pcK0eDy1@h2OrOZC6L7hmdQidvp9fTY5@3A7I/OzA7dKrTT6UC8jVx6PXO7JTRvFbcoa0XMwY3IX86GYfwtblHNGU0o9k2db@3IyelMVr590jUblsEgPo4AcXCudPE6C9zAnEtdpGI3M6Oup@RbTJaSk7aE6o4irbiXofFV8Ja/cmXLV@pRlD58@DCkTS65Q9sTu13Sa1l0ZxJynMfQlT/WuTGzPjam0HiOClieA/UDy7DZEW5a9xx27vDN0btmfU6IvbZBlx7u9R0YKf/yYXYN@5J77VtcE0Tg9dRAVdBu1/Lac0K86HXxRKjZ/weDUOrWIINIJDzALrz6HceZFWCDvTiZU8pngeIm3BhDmpsg@Onh50/PQ9/z0s7eU2md7R4/35/6ZESgDDsqHZwH1g3u60fNBCC@Lh0dTVvFB/qjPE2NLLHMhm/QWcSQE1W5XMl3brzbbL5vDr2N1GZmW3/8WD85AiwuJxm7sAc4DZHK5UjjxMtl1oQCFXYhvr7O1th6sVTMrgIhX@bSuQ/qFrTmKhS7BuQNbRNQfdJ3gShKwwF7YXhGk1hE@jqPV3lB08PmBZJiD1sYdGbL3rL0DHfpbur8yJnlSnTyEy/bw4s1PQkVSDSca5tO09XwZvtBj811hA86oRG4RRs642vHDyDVDIPB71MfiB@eYgF0LnTweBrkdsenMyM4bguxmiwlaRxZm9lMdnM1nU1kN7NrGX09k0no6YS@kd3YhG4wpWf19WxmU09k1zZX16CvBt/M5oYUge7LaiaTIBDpsgzfHIC163g/zBZetONo7aIU4YyTvVOMGBBEYB8w2YQ4Mt5U6Hp0EGHFKsjpNTwltAp1L8sGq7PIwcFe6uBAlnfRgusseylZbqAlk02lNnZl2SSfPZAn0rLs8DjgBcE8bkmldvdkecABoLYpWW6jpbSOozVZttCyt3NwgOl8g5Y0xodgl9yHWzq@ZQOC2WhZXaXhniy/DcBBuB2e0BrltIQWTBN9DrjPHvjJ8ud@flIpgHDKw3EIT/2y7uzI8iG37OygzxdU8AzP6pdo2aFHlvtgASKU5RYYWthByHINjEiKslwHU31kgBvexYMaiGzPkOURRxCiSJaHFNqoX8owKBHumMzTp0@NttcwW/wZ9fm3DlkDH2s4KB3UPv@81mrV@qOd0uen6PPFF0@Nb0aDfq1VE9FqVXgciAM@l93R9AN5PKxWjc5Mny/Bx57yqY6qJuataryFPImnhYl0q1@AzxfgM2MyeMihwdOFoDV8drvw3TVq5OM/5EPfYa0m55FQUTbAyVtsM5c28IJE16j3nTzah4UlFlWiiVF5PVXJkzvrKiCMpPK36N9U6L5XFOhRRBmVh4VUBQarG2lxmkmRL4bpjCUnlrrb@mYmt2Rs6@m1@DCH6sSdZpRFVX1b0R@vvFOex7bTq2s5@WJ7W5XLemU7rWdz6xuvVwayHMvhe3t1I/dOSUVBrsdXrLxR2d7IhGJsbMSNZDq3sRHL3wI2POigagPPrFYV5do0LmMxzC12@0rshorKRlRMK99UholhgWeKjWL5YUHPcz0YLHUHVgMVMQ2QC3OILcTIcDuVw9lzRdY3szJkIJlUYjFkSchE4Pvmlb@4F3xChgkjfzSWU/mlrHp2PabhwZiq06zSxXTsTTgkDlqkV3iKjU6w@5tNaZzp5qRzHONgL0AyllXDe6BJMwSM9rn2MMYnvvSNTUkqChH/hF@JlRfWz5/uaSD1CxvqdNIOUDx1@hpeW@1N@HB9Q77TOXSQ2lMTt5DWfbc9frZcKw1hSIcyru9xJM41aUIXg3b@NH@jVnH2/Tvnl@fn31Vvw2DPYLjDM4JncPKk9QJPs6MGLKvBjEIRTEZDoTwyI3ZNuKgWi4VqoWt2e94IBsJ8PwGU3I/9fNBlu4yHxZNx/rmgamEXkJTK26gE0kTrMhtGhlKxgTqudgu7N4Mcypa3ebNg9vtOX47gccJtuzCwXaNpnph9PMl2eIzSgIlnxurtNxclDLkHVXJzqxb7zB6X4tDlmAwOJlGWbjBLwqNaSN3mw/lWDLVYi006haxfcj28YwdEoPIdIA2OmhvazI2LRLf5ZkF5Hct3AIlibMl3ehv5txCgv8yUhrbLYttr@Yayy6oxdILeF19ptr6Wp5sUlDOKkqBUMcNGrFD8EpLjqV3mcpBfQS6XhR6M@ngqSpP1LFFbzYLVoHDGbb5VKKPbe3xtqbJcUdXy@woM2PNSEZhPfhQxCu6gxu8/TdVgrL6eH4KbvrGWb7NaofZ6mO9TOgw3LwPSIdK798rHX/tebEvNFLhbniK@74BQUdWqheG4wlcL5TQMoNPrazigXl@Fnw4D6zRux0ykU5uJtA6yBcgcEB9@G2Bfgx@EAdEjreOwW@koMEyWE6lhStMTuqknlNQbq/EmlrhUfHExlvCckg1UCA5IjEDHZIWvEYunVzpKw2HGlkpkDawvTyUyEm3AWqKNYE5No8ODx1S2uqJ0lhXC7vmgVypXcrnSsPcd8FLUt9vr8Y1U/F0slleWYgXXfEvIRDZJCOgtAY2JiQTmDrrl1BIUGZqkegsV7C3rG@lcebBcVnUoW@p9a0suyhWollsmwV94ORIkrzy4@QyRy2pjaWvs1kOpG4eYTN9M50UQqSf4syIrF7J/skKJRjfS0WgsmsfpsyVwF/ydeHEUeoboY31bBmlPzsmbafAfs/U7OeAD8XVditxKJFjDkDxyI93e3G6Ft6R9yUYjI6761seMteLLEkvSPhGtGmFLZFK1Ik1y7hR2Wqc7eRF6Z0@K5Giz5Hg/G7sQR@OZmlz61N0p8a3ia/69wG1ZkKxEqtzKrCImFtKrUOhGyA4FdG8kjlW@XSm5FS@y5IUky8Sx@Ap3NhPjeWUfItSY2d6NPyWRe4ajZ6YYOd54y5XYh@dW5ya7qvIRuMIiH1g8qdGOu2ryQwS6xFvCtb@78ss36Qxg33Z8Bxhre8DToQfNZGSczjPfsN7Z5uuN19nXz14cvzg@YE9SuWwuOzWff/EkkdCjenSLPQEJ3jotwcDtPXMy@gf7C74FNZKP5HrR1bXo6nTUQmRYWPO3MCh6sajqW2m2DbTKcsB1m/q6mnpf5IRXJI/1NPh8/LXfXhtuZcGeBkk5BzjNxNPFor6SjkV6H7/9t3iE8qb0cueIRVGhxd/9@e@nN/7uz/8VrZdHb/Poll7diEBINOrrG5Gbm97NzS083C8TqUR4ntY2YmDmezn0SDEpnPUNPRZxVW6D7GYi7nuh4UZJp7Lgt3fMbfI6YDOyGZEi2Wdv3jO2BaPqYqPVstJkSibvLJAs44AU/tkHnBD9oC69KRSXk0AAOLu7iRH8CbyVYrG4gisvLFqM43HgdIYWgMq3@QogFR8cm63Y9Ge6K/iH9tfcYcV1we57gxUn37dMlinqDMZzyeTHX/utdHr97/78Ny9i76vvq98FNru5ubmupyO/gHwsOKPnD8holgdP26EhGMixOVcyanVZitCsGOPh/WEdDuTwhDrX74M26QoFDEJxFfBogBStULAVPGmUIHmajiXH8pIUCJ4kL/db9QTBYCuo/xbajnQjPUIv6GhZAXiT9GgMChy6qBioXnU7g36PBECF4umVBHsMUSCFR6hKYolOSAkGp@p5lly5G5VnmWuVIRmFdU3XRW1SwH@lRxDlCKiULtJhPQNP2WFIywaGqmEQyid5NMqQdgXS7vAIVXJVqPQ8QILx3PFINgjV0iM8MkRCN3S8zNqCAHkWkx4BAqAMigBsVdgWW42xGysez4@VT93ibjfUPGD4Z3gkjIbQGnhwzY@cx3AWVzAx6KPSJSZquG6GHX0gHAZflynAcACjkw0lFjqm92BQAIuOaytUNPb48ThXBZBjYoxKhPBR9xYqzBprCrqTAADzx1GfNXJygtnxOFb2o0myA4zHKbtAdSoZxoGaeJgKrbeSBP8PJlqkyKmqIo88FkDUF28VdUAZREa08zqso/YwPb0RY0Hm65D3OmWKlJAEg8OL4Wca6QKq8yzeSr@I@AokJbzwOjScEXQ7fYiLAV8a4JVCeEKdMwNxPItfNoHM6dDzYwexoChWh0I3rT4MDWiNyVdnoqzqMYzWDFwoH7TLLb3GcANaJoYfioWhUemFgQokRDpLNI9NmrfcnmOTxgk6vYvb9EgPmCtx/Ro82wP72iDdUTwV2tUWyhFXyIWUT/qibK4Uy@VxcT2r1ocBro@bBDNbGqlWSW8yhSt5w6P9dgAuRpEowzAcNBDHtY7ZhSydmSZDrQduLplsWV57UCM1B88soKv2gQXdhu0mxeVFyWvr0kqeowI81WmCMCqO1UXYS6NjBRqHhC4BUhjWsS5NPkpVJs5Fuiy9ngBxLwGYHf8AsTmchcWzjynwTvBQ8NuAzwY3ZhOhuEvKKHb3u6ovKdUYiQWkDKaPFxRdGXYIv/S8l8TY0h25/qFnOoUHdi1gudAy@cmnKB59Co7kSeJ0doFODms4Pd5TQJzyz@qhEURM8wpCqLqEfQwwzbp/iBBbMZT2EXUA1PagZaFWEK@fw9O1BdSXpdSh6QkGb7PP2Gqarn3n583F8XCAgVVfmIQOfhAVy@F6DagYjU8tAF@B1tltgF8EleRw8sP4PnWjmTTkjMmbLQlw2OlQWgXGm4VvyYQs2Dq4vjMo@hJ4rkMOZ@RkSZHjADYux2QOOog/HZ1Tu0S8JMfuQkowhCBQDVBQVNg1XK4LU6j0uL6@1kirzKBvaaaLSkpdvHgt2WtZII06Sc/s9sT9EhZeDiQuPhubVK6kGO/p2x7S9Xibj0f8K0lNPOf6dmD1TSXadKPYB14Br@y1unRkHw/Tu0Q3BxYp7a0rtOzpCjJLVxI3PpnlkMzUbPQWgTCGYIaJUaKeAGCJWv0y0bxu5IXHFbU7AA6VZfqOqPCt71u6rm@yes0ghOPRhlnfXutc1p2Og6KHzOdOx0nzEvohR75V2HvWECLZ5jXb6feNkUL@MQyNdKqMSLphI@jdyQeM0JuwG64XyRqWR5WJ6MMgOvRd/tiD9fHAvnSzGChXR4X@Q@4/BP8h9x@OE/WTLQ8rXPJCp1ssDhI36t/xQyKYkR/mlmvTGvsQZJCLmc5BYMjRhNst/OoFiu3jm9ugHgs@YQBNkBI7BbXnlS8qtmter1TiyRbQtEyIgBoH0OUK4fS6EZgR@52rTs9xJ5xsVE8DnY/INzrV24IaOK1gGYMKIsLg@LJQi0mrq/HJH97viwIDBBS3wBMlgB1PsWL5QH8oeQLhlOUxjnnGyiIzFRKyhJdwA6mIo54jNgyoEgKE7kGRIJvgw/yWI1RQCybwqo@3dfphVbojgRShRitRwORUU@EsJU@VFMqVqvrZBLSjVFqYLorvD1VRnvIKFfNW1H84@0ufnP0mtIvZuSeC5f1CXgo3FXOISh9N0VwIq6xYCNUr5CC5YnTMPnRQJS6Gik4ZkllJ@qMJng4WgSsrVUKVX4/x@qGzCLIt5wJSGBUKUMRRgTdL3i58lHKEB9FcEW3kE4KIzxkIwEjNjGaKaMNwtGGhwBkHG86Jdh3K5JAyOeRReOjhnExWRDQYJAXqMLF6KqgFDQQqGeDpvLdEjZ8yc40rVOvKvkGtJTB48tMc8xyiAkFDKEkjndUrM1MvhzIdYlpTAJAQ7wBo8BsvctI0w9PVwBbwKI5Kn0dxmyADziuAwIgF57lmKiUgMhrqglwvx6kfgLYrx8uSrOO2I/pL8Z@c8B39n37XMTUZUp90TCWm/v5BHCuI2VADDQkZemoNGTIOWHZIUQeIJdcOU2YIz@Ce9K80TdY6Ti3ZNXAnBd59HFx0GvPHA6SK70nP8QzPWVvL8UGQRfT1QgRnIW3zfAxgtWwHhhphzXcW19RnR1EhYd1p2ZZrJvBqVS6Cm7TAz5WDS2G5VxgdV5LErB8fliJoTkAoulareC1Ptaq4ZqcZywVqJdGqIR1GoxKOZ8EUig98SAA97ikO3ivtxe6HiWohRbRzq36pHPeEZxQS2WHArOogz4NvG0QV5jrjkSDpa0PRuOYppBq97XSdFoh3qIsRY0@BPxzDxgwZvR7lJcEMHKLmQsozqTko9YQRE1G//OSo7Mu0YsSC@OlJABPISLD@NI4Rs/0ZyVXnJsej@emdfXp@z8L5PVucXxpVT@eZD7UL3PPTkl5VxhAg4Dgbq/dnIyFUH9/JzkRWAmcUoHiEB2exQTuVGpjTHQi6I4JrTaCPRGBzSSGLyPjLefhfXIF@9NJDq8/AW8rORsBvurghTqHLAVx//U@B4Icx5D13kwtIe/@BaUFYkCPYAcoKIK8S47JR2w80zB4Mo105WPIQgO@hedx5dIfuaTtSgXvOyFP/KsEu0/OraL/aMDvGyGwoImQiBNcv8SmMzIhfPazgyOiI6Tl8UKdAJxULqwpGpPNAuTkkYySuQoqi74ThQayAemjmm3J4OB9/6H@HNeOUXYHPPoPAH41GSKc4qYDvjXojriWxw6/QEHyU9z@8JvFE5v0IATyIrQuJcbKxRezzVAmK9IAeIQirTRaZ9CH53ZbT7d2tw09D0f0lhcoNRSr4tTyhx3lejVuLajxEFT5N8vWch5HkfUT3YJoLkRoHNmZhe5/WhdyBjHse6nUlDJG7LKwxx77DE9CN5t3sOb1KdQZDDWISp/MsGleTfBGTcAh8CF@cQHoJXwTYMr0qJyi/bDhHJS5bYeTTNXohqUW4gDQOUEJY9LX1UzZCoSTfDMFvboM063PTrN9Jsz6RZtACJpMMBZLqE0mKWsDqWVQFHbPpzeHO6IWDZPgsYtvw2I7Rx2mJm6gVzVkJFr2K5oAhR81orqQAU442orl9MrjR3BkZLqO5L8EwblvR99Gc3ywwQB@sZHiC7oKFo70eze0psVvJwwsV/HS1aC6oUwizza2EEUAFlhukRlwysx1RTK9vQsdGQmWCIcW4CRwn0YRLgn4p@Oea0/kNH@CJc5YrFJjFmT7RaYR6DJ4OdBu@Ts0ZLTknevPS8QHtGRqrpgf/OAzmwnEIPIjhkegkM@IZQ19aoYAvZBD5Zm52jpg@eX/BA7IjUgcKpUqeTJ@wp5E80FDIvwyBK7FJtfgivl9fkyB4BT4snxh5Xj7vZMdPjnKEa6yxGdlCpL6JLigU1vXUnQ@89sM1RHPXk4HwVj8/CK8lAhvi6SDD0WIbJtZzepNEQr64nc8Kx6HZN94okXqnohFXEC1zjjc5i5IhYwg3/tii4oTiYdYmWBB6llMV3sqCfoF4MXqNeV1IUuWND7IQ4jnQws36pYlkuy@MFI6zmwT1FfO6IT8uT5I41ySbhMgaqpYYGB5PPRi8llDhxKcNX/2YQ5xUURBAKGaQCuevzifI7w6X332B2kfCVAKzBOvZXeld8XphLzuV88442bsViJ4Jth@bKRwFKYxRDqODkGS@iNbuiPi4hYML@TzRAPqUtO@jLRgT3IO36bEFh4VSQv9q0vEyDY6X6fmIuiuRdK40X2jRMCUBhxc8yOm4aIvzygs@q4rRhyayjc4nV3B/soLDlYfwqAD9KZTzVo4HBXFta9y2SWEpuiBL1XOMM3Ja/gyqeewI7J6WYoNlWHA4rp7uHz8/@ho63Y2NjZjoo0fj/GGrxUnVoB/nkGnTcdAfzBi2pBOosBsXr3HenW7JXLqw5Tu8hDNrEAbwohKf/EQbjwleFuLnU20X4vGwIYwKWJfjZmBMcCUUdQzssi2BVw8QYnrKiiGA@OIt4DtBo7UYzskCdeCdZ9UqdV/VKm5GqlZFL4ZV469wx34RWUoO3D5dT8jVCV9LEh3rZfvH7NXTnXN2/rTEDl7sfcm@Pn7BXu08P8djsScvdo8O9xj8Ss/PSmw8o4APXrGAA0rA675ZN7s1YNnpVGqNEeQ9pzfifEfZi3H3M6PLnjp1E9ejtlyj@6TNLZptekUeqwTD0ZG4abuHR6Y8j19PVgdwJNw06IwabttnELYGY9oujnm7TsNqWhBWwrFvzzJd/8wU61hQg8Bv/fOOCS4k4XUPtBWIrvqiW9rwmi8Ij4s0AMZwx9fKWS6PYDY0JhAXPJ@MwfPS6bMztvN8n@0dP98/PD88fn7GDo5PwXry9eHzzwGfh2fnp4e7L9CLAj473j88ONzbIQeegZTG8OAz3du2KAsaBies1C9xiZuuGw1s4VlnCAYSPLs26LSey6IDG7mPZXSsd2YjmpfwIhh@QpDWBFhwDRsz3@JSpr/mS/sJ5BcuXWWynGJblBo0liK0t7xortDtoVJpXHjojhheaWPm6TyyQubxVTm0KadhmUzewz0nOPfNjy1TW/ZBQ0JLABtB@RtQCow0tEejiS0CWYTU6h0HlWvx1PimQGHBqE/8rSN5iTAm9r4gUDwNcGjjfJCeDxyA7sEhLZL1@jwAWw0ceAC2xh1QFD3EvSAsI0IMvOMBsme2zh2@6fYOaP2XbQQOuwaNYrMiT7zeqEoNNr7G2Or2OqRjn8/y0NU5hlu3LIriUnjUUd/p@PfX1UwgeeCJ4rYh3KsGIWVgNk1cahDb2OwBNWzwBWrAfT9G03OZUohp7Bw3@5i2xS8vaHUMm29pGm/FIdpjWVRKURC7ra3gVoAGv0OcCBBv6pjMRxBvX0iF5kPjQczdOykaYs8j3Szjbym7LwO7dzLwy4ABQOrESKdOPRWdzkQwTlOQsuI6QJE4b/shHB7IuTGomxMR/NsFv7HevYsJJCcmxkn@vkPKHVQRXsSY4GuWTacPbZzYahdPqyAXrLednmfxOlQmSzC@GwpCY8cGqb0pFCdSo/sgp1K0HTuUaA2oeE6qNSDKh6RKFM8XyQP25bf14HIq2keH2TFqzpUZWjtL4CLStYnTLyAI84v1sLehi1KF/CmNeccHuuwwWyju716oH94kULU@Zwv8Oil/EyG/HLGLaUHzoHU@2oDYR7lLtDT/fgZ3UMPYYk@d4JbYyn1gMA5sWzCue1LNB358@/Bddzw6Mu1Oju/fF3gsFTkT58gDt62MuVuClf0kExSnwsRejxDvhMwCr1d8lwTBDPj1EzwngrWQB4zYyEfoWtPJexEEC/FLVxs0gbOIm49EdQfwY6xIWyd8QZIeJVwfydfKbiFejCXHO0dYCJ2Kz6ITPmS8GGm8/4T6qzvg9heDA/79cHDZhbnj3cMnQdtfCO2T8qbG58Pi3VII1sPBflgAlnduvxRYKHtiPmDeSd6FFlB6QJyJ5UiwO3Zxim/u1B21PQCDfS/OoARAQ6kNbFqi9jVgKjxCLAxmLBCdne@XTk@ZzMcnEBf4Hg4ZGoINIuwlfm0E3z1r2cTstEBoCgbLgfDku0xsXQuOfCxozDORN4dVCBkkIfARMIvJSxqJ64mehUQI2k1PDNHH3GTubnwe5JYF4FtUeQrMKzIWw4ICSjOLGeGdj@WGN3ULvCW4bBzek087pnnfjdct9UdhQOHNP0YLT4rMrr9XXD7O@elwAct8O6ACN0CSxhtHNXYGCfcgoKZN1uCCavGrFDfNcwE74uMOd3ilJiXsvz9BESFxIZzLwiG2LoRjkTUuHy/7Yg7tPMRuwMAtncKT71AGD5/Fk8tWuEJj405PmeyCQMjEi4CehKkColdu88Hdocq4nywEAnm4rS1Tbsp@Lis4Oytg5@cH@gz3Nq9Ps4fppIDbLkxK/dUkxXuJiZR8nM8sjO8JkNczmdX7YE@Xwo@u/n1h8z5kmn963R6M78cg3ZFL0/tAuYfPE77/mAAWoI5vlfcbzFREEHVm9CkTZafOKJw/yAufF4LMoFLZehuvPZpMNcaGU3mbDZ33SGHoFOROGUJNOCgobzV3sH@7ODlkyPemt/Tp6fHGhoFwj@DtL4LDdSE1KSEnPCY66Wb2@zYF48eSug4eH6PTSAvPzNGhOb6hlRcGPWmZLVyApjhkxLfVJvwpBkqEZhU1vCYNJ/Xy07N6qp4Pl/Dg8KjEVkjbWXNiClLuy7EQy1my7EUZINZL0xHYa9BRvM/cHPwgDwkfJKCJDuUphJvYvXkjjICwXCZt/WLbp2Cp@nSlN926YaPOjoRMNww/hog0@Vo6PojNmlBP5SfiQ@bcnq1ArISsajJFBTecx0VIkyB4baJ7qJ@SUFu92CC54FJVI6lnU@ubEpXOTniJbnmzklipF2QGfa5hd91B/7px2XLaV03WYb1vasP66N1bxjJrDI/4ph9zvY76egFPtyoM74HKss0UEazI4DbpqLyQGdNIOR@uJ7Px8Du/hCoH4aGxcg5PQExRKVvp@lSIJ@W8Qre8XinYhVS@W7YreTyr58ULXlyPK@jwGDpPYC18Qb7sVbAr/UV4ttW0r1h/UBvBKCk4@8Ho7Af27zjDJfZs03w5bTOWHuFmNTxDotnmtRJcGI2UKaH8Iz2iQzw6nvam6WKcbWlYkAPAfgKEVXdI71FMepTSBj3PIR@RkIokxN5b76VH/qmjFE0YQJCyVfGzs0VwxmEUXPfhriO@G1rVuTSm41HHWAhEGWMSt5MvZBmPAGJGxdGrckVyNdOotzETeDXge4rGtrb4neG34E2TdLhTw@jTwYdUBY24vgGfHi0mYBIkmLt0fEOC4qNdRwN3oSkoj8670EZ3iQRB9MFt3OyGjiNR/C1AAEf8Iy5SaWIGUwhWICfyo340d4Da4ybH9biKgKcgeaU8wsIibJ5eYQycdnwTjjBZgSZwf3SN6OS4gkeUQNXJdqcYQfgYD04ooWVoYXMRl1Sl5FXET2ccTQlFU/1ofuAQKh7diw2cyILRzzMTms@I7ZmdDmSa4@LRGB1opOO4Iv14kL5bxjQrQea5v3rHX53w17g/z9Q4lAb99zhQLhxIjtyMw90yeRwscSetAiPZRIOarmsgcYzD5heFdTXPqVrjwMWgKjlVBh5bEx5qyOf1jNrnPksTcQICD/zL3F/Qd1rUfJDLibBPJtPHryQqyKS9sWIryRSVarbV2eadU@CDZCYzvISeR8f6JrLjjVIcmRTsBAQ0nManZlssjKHEdZ/jUJuRi1tPZE0IE9vKdDb4ocM7DWtGGwlhidKME@KGdL4Q0iHvpRAIgomExvyWW/Qjj0TkUQgshlryk@WHFu80cCjadBMv4DHG9/jyG/tk5vxwkdmej3jOh7zw/DDyJIKI6S7Js9E0yU3w2Ad3FIVa0IuM0x5NQ5zNJJ6HJnmDNE1@ZLqJs9xLAZ8IMwqfU9zBe@AjMD0OoPvkO68K0fNW@kVyRfrcABG61zGHbAdHEQadppImzqN7puu5qMcIFVjC8LzX6@CiIgl213TiWejmSGdwNWUMMbSMpkmHuHGHh0@gSZwfh0gaO0bI17j/Y@zhDlotfuM8Q81KwFpxQsXyNGnHHvH5Cmgzq2l@KtxkA5cvisJgvhXOBK853noQ03RduyaBLOaClCPxojZ5@xbT5XgsBLVsQZeWk6TvDKz65d7nuFy7oadW9RDKrsRqb0pbXRsflAIk@R7pFIirGX1NkkJLv3W@9KsiwAQ7wo7@JdCmeYXX4ko70GNQQBeEU9fsX5kNTZJOzWCNF@EiKePCIx6bdgb9Op@7AdkKr9PF075ugq92AYXhF/tnvhpcp6WwhIRrUuPFZKjqK6uBCPQPlDQdXPyl9Qg81c/xgZG6pgdIWYmxySzR0rLIC8kuXZxnAmygWpLQ0kOABtvxrDrUDE1USR0AxVc5xonxy79DOYH06h0DD/lqszKAp1/GGPAz4K8ULcqDJNbEPykPTBTMX0I3/JpJAvdzqK1Aczf7FnDfMYKpVihaKO9QwedPD8/Y2fHB@aud0xID88np8cvD/dI@2/2alrBxHZw0vLKnx0fAXYLFcr4ofgwO8s4ZxJTJQ9p5/jUrfXVyWjo7Y8en7PDZydEhQAPwpzvPzw9LZwl2@Hzv6MU@La4DBPb8@JwdHT47PIdg58cJStWPJo3jseMD9qx0uvcUrDu7h0eH519TigeH588xMVy032EnO6fnh3svjnZO2cmL05PjsxLDgkn7h2d7RzuHz0r7GqQPabLSy9Lzc3b2dOfoaKqgx6@el04Z7QEIlXK3BLnc2YWhKqZE5dw/PC3tnWOBxqY9QB5k8CjBzk5Ke4doKH1VguLsnH6dEEDPSt95AYHAk@3vPNv5HAonKfdgBepl78Vp6RlmGjBx9mL37Pzw/MV5iX1@fLxPuD4rnb483Cud5Zl0dHxGCHtxVkowvJeIkgYYgC3wB/Pui7NDwtvh83PoM16c4HaGGFTyK0AM5HIHou4TgnGXA5YWkHR8@jVCRTxQBSTYq6clcD9FnBK2dhALuGFi7zwcDBIEJJ6Hi8melz4/Ovy89HyvhN7HCObV4VkpBhV2eIYBDnG/xddAOpDoCyo11hPkixuBWCWfchNUnezwgO3svzzEnIvQQAFnh4JaCG17TwXOoS0npdBkieXg3IDRDU@gNO86XZFm7rszL7PnYgIFR3vH@yWQ@Lj@LHns/gI6neyU4qOwH3Q0gSdYJxTMNMzaoFW17KaDR0WDaHx@o@u2EnhXQwxG5@xCWnBdh5hGoQiRSLX6cqf6/7X3ZNttG0s@m18Bg7YISNy1m4JiybZunImTO7GzeCSFAkmQQkyRCAFapG3NOTMP8wPzAfMp8zCfcj9kprZuNCDIUpZJcu9JzokFAr1UV1dXV1VXVYOe@7Lbdat3qZkB47YaYuT@WClXxogZ2lHxRvvOo0eM9r0MovZX5BiT3PDweAFLMvJX2LHNvwhcq9EYBFINY/CxYWUhivlQ5BwPSoAzUigj3l6QdkkGCPodCjVQRUc1X@930QqKfo9UaBrDP5MP6Q/eG4wXwJzZqtVooA5LYITvAtUNd0KZDegfSSwQDqnLehwEb0ZO0@wOVf76aDodOK6r6lDZBNTAkePeUr0XjHLVa/n6BCwdKkt6@Fip3STB6NNlQZkl81Kf0cgc/Keb0B9XQcOpG9AmSl2RKVpsk84KV0d/o6olGSoweIImGUW@FwffPf8Wlblme6OTe/@pfs9rC70BMZss7HfHVO@U/nx6ygVggVFKDUBJKIkuGg2jjvIm0YUvoeA5FqL8@bRVnwe0rQNKQI6d@2OzT9yMZ@HChB7Y8F@@Onhx@PXREXBOhHZjZ3N7q1PSSbK@q/Lf19gP5eikHGERbOMgptEnY5U8AbmHVoqREzslfyLgRgMLYtZxNWn0EtM1aK@MrJ8S8jEcboxXeUzQAc8OEA@2RXk07pcUvRauTCEAJzNUF0dz4S9IwvdBVCIaEFeV8ZJmbYH/YNt6@aslrgckBCQkRjlmgXJBuSC@Zx8pR1DSbSjNDhap24qOOemaxgFZusg7FmNn6ZfQtjGLMTsq4nqlaaeaAMT9PBSW8pqY8Mr@K6ULETsv5fqCN98JvcHja0lHR8np/Dg5SF4CGo90TTRHpzZnGfSxtHy678EUrazonvYsNOa7AhStPbEa6/wexmogUE7RZdCzcg13dDqQfJfk3/q44lrvmVIxBwe20xGKld9AuUXDkVY6Kg2I/FbJJSxuS@cqYaxd6j5KqshrnY5CoTODpl@ED2r/d8RJQft7oHBC6ym2jJR9d8Iktcq4Au2VkBJeqvME4xAjxab56nXazJU5Med6YHJIs@DoGUCBzM5SvXhNSQqHTgECkMjRrmGuX@1wdu6D5vTYdqU6HodM@heRY8leobaKa@2eVknmqqoDFPzhWi4bmozuPoeK1mP2kUtE4QIu1ltaD2Ob21hruSp3R2OVjB56lRNpnrMjap6cmrK01OKXNEnGLjPQ2Y5AFL268URu1TKyWGYYvpxquR0zu6U5YEEb9LmPgBaOGz3w2RU3my2RE6G/ogx2mFwbdWbciiTdXI@cLscBtvNwQJYRvGM0ucTtYsytU5q9tDXLeUhOIdhJ6mGY5ghE5uvWAeu0yV5q6MlMifSqof96wvnlAzZxqRJ1TuYhEJqh8XXrhb9EmMd3G7eddr6GaN3P9v98QqkH@wnvlNE0Js0dekFN/2GcYkS54cA@lGJJ/C9tRaPhZS1cwB/qqyYjV0kcQWegBJNFQv/VjQoB5ZfMnpBa9slEG5Ee8UbmPVTiCz7x2tVPr/FJ7MweDAqAgzd4nCpiEIKMchMe4V1fbQQf5ob7NgxmA9MsB7vpwI/QAkTi93RC266yXkkGub6fxMESpNB@I1w0qI2u89n0fNJ9Mh37o3Aa@qArYArtBS9AfFzSI@b/HM2mlzFdvkIfBkahwTJ95gwmnNELf@ujsY6R5SlOgsgxT8ST2fLgnBMRkPEW3cwszTMpiWqUT7el62xsppVK2QhH8vhquZ0b6663iirz4TE2IMtqP3dYz1GKCYW@GOGNnWsFeh8rYMDYs2qW797gE5aBeBdQRCcBGYgVMNdOwM1BoHZwI8THg0V1QOnsZpjKJ3ga4PUlsUOvqz5eDQmc/hM8lH5ktXaaRlU25C8wpR0@LG9Gd3v7d4YeAPgF4LfWi6iliBAooe9Q5fOJWWaWvJQAi77IrIqaACjJ01k4AsV2nGm0u8i3mv28vAkb5GQCW7NkbLtGlbgiHRC@8Rovpwssp7t0rQ8frIpVcSkzBO6IB4nTvJlgg9s8NGnx4zkiG2@QMT2Rlh0D6JtQ1Qcs4b2AOQdOE2TOwnv7imm37zprOQR6RU5Nxg0Bjq32S4pxEJkHT1amM2DGdg574m1QiZNpVLkj9m7kHYVJvopw3XfdW11Nmdi8xVp7dUCo9Zb4uOyU8vDkiCaLMXJqAhpCFYqeNZnnkbjwurjevO7yFjzchLPURUdvKnq@B7z2cVN8iz6jaqPRS4pgx3yXHf3@uAsD797MQaRNFvG7xDG6yDK6S340msqhSWPp7hgi6hPYc/gYAOaw3wHgzpyfG5Ga98dS2TPVp0y@RMQnpvrGsEDgS9EQz/8xERkfkWgmxVnNg0eY2JVOk1q1HuarxQ/cIAarBLXUFsJWxHSycnRE@eSHThcdVlrIieBp3zxk12niNcIoj7sYGOTQvbustU473NJCtwSyLJX6WEsqohl@HncX1Mo1VMASL0CFHtE13nR@91H90rFAOWiBa9Nn8SVtVnEwrrUG0MA/5qfuAmXgtCupmVlR2YXQJdYAawHUkNE4YO0Jpb9wxhSPB@yyjEC059cO/lmTGpgAequpsY1VFoMlFnEF3bzaXKu2z1VSguLfiH5ZiizqkroEDQQMMdT3WtACZsgk6NEwTcldTMrLACpzBBW9Fi5LeEkJNlOXwoLviFQpsLFplGgWldg126gVNgKCRXGZFBCQWYqLpK3ARlcIi1Fiu3g8aQkQiBXtM8ZhKmRWsjjUM8cIhEeCVnOU45ZVbQoF08eNTTfzUdM3fd1tGl@b@a@AHw3hca2V/7rTzHzNdNtuZ6tmagI@XLPXzEdAhWsCrLnCL/uPgh/M7NnaLdFQMjJShrgCT1CVukS9rf5DbO1R2K@SMVR7ZuyxUr@6fClHJr/3x3N5W5IpvvPLB6t8IxUgklyeEp@paAqH9UESWG3c6XFUqOiqVG46Al6ptNOh9c2ro6NMXtHeUrm6XASzzWaziTTcM9OoKy9etF@E00a2dGM4H48b0eVns296DWL9eOX2OJ4@Ugp0ADMCayKuT2cjvkoAYYCiWLomkZKo6s@HQzNnPx6S4dzBrHFJCbe3aP8JtdvFN6/IwENNyv56hgPE8Z1ZevFd@ixnSivqJARqo1PqW1sd4AB68MUQPYH1YQk1hnxZ@dPAtuV6@@9xA8GrMGiyKBGu@z51kLU/DcbjadX6djobDzAU/d5VvsLRkVmhyUXwkIvCR@cxJTytWsHbcGwErmIRk9SxObUvqYsJVIZxzLL@VTB6togc@/h7G3YVGPIaDnMNMx1XLXtku5J2/A7NMh0C2HcqfeFHTp/wlC8MO70s4PQJIFpvVQtVn0wRl64YEZzdXhqRWgxunbIBwNBdEgVUVnSaXhrJDcU1cu2TRWuIOGxyGwITJvW4Ww2MZfr9uOLbZDi8G1OkhPI8sb85QySLNK1AWX6AT8zH/E81WNZHuYwVLN/gtQ/X@Q5W6GKFUulh3/vx0jk4OLAeRGtr1sHBITzUatbB4YH1FF8cHlpP4fch/l7x2pubHea5T9338PJQvbyyDqENMnCu9c9nT@EnfPMwMAn9hXGKHzS8B9XOg663t9@JG8cHhxg3Dk9/@7f/@Nu//2fjQH78F/44pB/H3@tC9Xq98aD//sHKVQd/Hz89rTzoHT@ITiujDlIZsvuvZ7E/9g0Hxnq/dEuQzmAc9m4K3NEeHGFM3oLosefAP54HGtiHD/x0kqSPs/QR03Km1f1xdO5TdYta2PcqB5WVFXja8yr/UiHbibz39ft38N5ykZdT3D6hFq@esQ5ePnn@3Mx8jVyfpPdhgGla8GZEOTYJJ3EIgzorqzvnasdWvW6d1qwzDR66GnS5YBZEVjMZmH8VINXoyC@Ezk9FbcCDUTJ9s0Wez0ku4hHJd8p0zvdv@aKpPBw84kMdamMNGB6W77C7tIRe4vABXDyF8WrHra3N01q5XC7pO7m6fWJz1FtEfek7mtQxLp3BcCRQBEsGxk53pHmIC2gQkVEu041NK32@WcyZoGpNGhMr3OWKIc@jvYkGUtJsji3cHM@PMhYqfHQLlhXPKRAAZYPlXY@UAACK8NojxmXxLbtxFPTD4VIfu@OlCGnvsFdi1NaqNbwWtGXZs54t47o/TBsEhKAUQOlisNF8g4y8KZQNidvxGNVvEDeuE9WZ5J@2NmiCtVNKNB0vR2PozCF3nvgSuBNg3pXJGk9UNBf2wDV7wRCvd@cVzROWupMi3L0ATRGTPiiYA7yiaIxpoVjg4yNISogI6wElHLmibIjRCM54wk4s0yE8woaPgVx8HRuR4RpuqUJQqNSicqyuOBM@sBq5rhVxScQq/E4PgIk8yARJ@rDctZY5CoxcqYlv94TSIrxdDhVpSU/pykqyaa3oA1iQKi/wgAwPxwApWLJO11kBa1haZ@PJmR4/H6nFeCMenZ/xhXPUTZvPyIFj6W5UxDZ1x@7oNhtX6fKriZ8IeqNpHIc9QFayVNNEWfjYf30GrZ5UStyZUAse1CGC8dVqpFeUOT5FSsEiohBxhvcemnYnigoyBfFYEc/E@Gy4nDkpnkwnNWK5vSAJ@@zEx73fV7w4wmNa8t4nwG7uCJQHPqhUE0w9nKgEN3JGSVOdtkN4Qn95XP/nWvT2CWdi5hUWLbELAJAmDj07JymS0hY1JVADWaQIjOSCLBi8lyHMcTAKk0ydqiQBYM9nHsWVQj0u8jME2MRuDrPoq0@rsmfsM2eCb@UegIxXfQNGu@NK/G0R7anB4K7Gdx/qmjwkCunauU4fmh8pcEyoYQUD@nD5VrMzRJsr7nWUxwyzSQ6ypGqls/DRHqhxAZH5xSrFmFADwi3yOKkdAzbaOWwAO80tg5QLNzPNGwSMxG3u5MSjcujl6WKR4BrzVvSiIEUiuCrpqJL3/9/9ZqayN8MQWVh8UArpAPbo1M1Bp3LIN1m4Ai8DJahLfjZgjbM5JkVj9wnZUTCLSsiL1OhUw5HrSg1dZrhGklJEKTrg53HFnMtcVTXetPZptnatwlFF71VskWNIOpErIUfy9R5v5q2tTdUuBw3R0Rv9ulLRTRIcpH0m1OwIyml79YeIHvTCoGt@9ORcFZGG0uEVl1djFskChMtM49QWHdFIOdMTpQBJ7KtwME@mz5NfX6an9MZy1qdf0o2fIBf4IAaLiOC7DXmCR/SAdX8ttQD5QAiMgH2o/DiA51KJJQ/RMO0X8ehwunCa1RP7xK62tnZdm/RkLYeV@zFoRuV@wAm78NZA0T0pMSDZtd8GzMJnvXAwCCYqHShUld70p640e4zm/Pea3cV8yapNTDywDV4e12AS6YXgmp6jmT@68Onxi@mrmb98DpsQ/fxywvP5Etv7CjYjvBaIvnzFa/RgAKKGfYV6ckoTdxoihSz5IPn0ExINOBmcIS4UICC4hgDuU48/zg7WQIM5frZdaOmZ9k2Y1DOWUGJ25D3jg5OzEt85e4GXonb5HdCmY1xKK4/0KXdTssgI@EH5mBlvuQaL@mM86QkmmXMIlb1WCI9vLuZaVWsMBNpUKtfHhzJln9wzDX18JopN0j/vXszHSSgjuzYsNS6slL9@l9RJdWPyDVfwkskwjztjHNjucQirNNVliFGlWBAlTLVi6I8K3TR@MjumQoOoKpx5or1B9NG86nxkbli631eqBiaGMA5slHKK4ywZ6gbU7pTSfdbSo76fUT4QDkAKgrEa0d3HxJqvzDnGGcbUFcRM9OT@Fjr737OSy2/otCHFktJLMfoVRAbmYamuT57tVasph9iGVguUwpdfTy8C0WxFnTCUV@PiMs7n@LsrrLdobhnpz0CV8hw2ZZf7mYWWEQ6Vy6aBTi3E0M5szgKN1RRGTEmCWE4ksfmMZ2npigOjC9kGKyVQkmHOC9lKYtIjLWBv0MS1zbOqxYhrn1wlvWkJiIoCTQ0UU5XdLd3Y5NJrtOqlO5iCNStTmiK7lW6gqcxaoIRrMrgVUcF1RLV@HqIYriI88ZdfDU1ZBGSxdFUqFZGvZh3immWudR3Fco0vEeLua0E410aBoNsbY966FLB8c3hpvEj2u0oYXrUORsAWs7Iwe1j76TvWeliBjHNRy9oQx17x8xnmdS2DdFWC/zHHLnCpCzToZCwgILI2SroQxSghNgjf2hohUfNWo@yWxGeoUeabalrbLZc6uUNPGAT6C8R7ZoN4FDO8FoCFGwqJHKtWV4LYbt/9aK@7wSydGV@hSRo4cmqUZva8GkXoTH6blbpRlmwKjgXNW671Mw3UZCtp8x6Edp5GuXQPQGBJA9O6QWdUe00MvHEAw9BJIdmcm7phsX6oDN1/JPu3wrHyVRAK0AJCU0kHKJ/RLcQ8wSIhUDAlLdDKw7gCqNahHIW9pKIaiYuE2gwlqx28JVt1oUFIzwrt0rGVXuI5SwyrYqHVVFmIrHJhNcvBLJdozaCjo6CPhnBtpYpdwx4sZocGtC2XQgNYHKynm8ywK3M4KyuWwEYm65yMUajoZxDFcGSQcTJh5pwnXWBC@JIQL1sKLBMt9UWF9gcuICXS1blSLIgge03lkNRC00jxPp9ozBdjh6p@DD8UDDHNBbkQToij6vQjKTSln4rQPD5vIVIy6P39UOlPmom7kqpcHX0TLfJevN3ivdjce5ZxA60NuPvg37DPsaYU3JjuP9aqGQB8j/dfMlPAP0ygFK@Q6EB24PZx4sp11/dSva4eJ12@uVuzX9TjxOVuMIDtGJgtRTZVQU9MyAfJMvCsHGwpyP0nbZhKSefuhRWCiomg5DUzqZ3qZRYpZob6qyLjCVNDCSW@B82RexFFE@LR1bTPsemwQeH3IUWmk17bYrUIFSKueIw/JcTv3pAz5Q1lJfMIrNWudCtjEHhoECxjHc785E4iVnokxw77@vL6PB3G9ZL1/KeLZHeRy1bvLJeVV8mmvZqKZ6vlCGSL9Z/Zxm8rp6UGWmjH1pDbuFDJgE8qB6AYJmiMHsapMV@4lnnk9vPFvj/Flz/qxrD6hxdfVjX6@1khZjUVYvqFQkxaQGr10fBG9XR5Yg@wbCekIa@K2MP9TbP9wbpR/U0L@@PLwK20nFSeUrf4uqDb5HIqNTShSodkfyzsCHktr@kzW9b2meVcX9A83@k2vP7nNvyPvQ03NC4w4eUtO40x9X/O/T/C3GMKxfFOc6fZ/dXOffU72yQsO3fealn2fau1/8n2yeJp82Sxu/Hlj@WkvN9ufDuDv0n5x/LWTpkf4QF@ratfb8v75T0stnVVXjY8z4NHaeXgCFrZ/0y3iaWWe/DP/qZqd2tZ3q95VP1DeX8LHlrtNkBysni2e7LYaeL/duePJH6Ypyta@Lip1YjyqsiGwGeB4iJPavk0Tpt8YuwOz5EElDqeNZDizg@N1ghgdJ5ZtHeaIqsAAXH@h7eBXAF1EeDVXdo8RTlMEsqjwREXKv@D@OpxJVgBugsX/lAXtNuL6JXmnFDpJlBKSIG2zh7Wt/Do@kzSUGgAdOIJEjPZlRvUC4c6xhRb@He/@YmtE1M8siVvhW16/MvZpuyKO7Ir/m/ZipbJ@XTSLkisXraewHQlgfVDzLDEkzCKgoQl/lEwCWBLRmN6OEVBB2966@O9eOPwDbv/PVKNW31qqPtD3OXYHG6oHi0t@8FjWFnhBWlF72BVqmc8H9vaUL@AceOdYRgno6JrRmFyPu9RTvxXs@Xz5EvKRNHAvNoJZ6VogCzXa1z46DhAmeRjIDEoAexgNp806G4xENgwVgbTv1/4bwA0vM8UhjboQjE09r9x6PLQOIgoxGUxHNp0U08wHrwMIn/mc9Y09Jqf@6PgOSaGgcmIz21UnsrWFxRck5jZcbWyRBgHOVyuZKpxBivi/XFFhX8Sai0Lw43pxhgb49SFCRHvtusUNQG1bA4toFuqh9NpkpbnqHFdgX5ma1BOMJgkDg3Bw8F0RMDNcfxrCog1y5IXBEf6UzpNX1BHBM3MCvEmBxxVMJlfEO3om1WPW49OJW@a1zJuuCaP151Hcqu5bSNCcZrE2NzawS9z9r2kc8mSpA7Q4wDBmiGBgjwhczotvABNIY6nvR8o7w9yJViQSH919U2WPbnRwyMauyfByCdecdkLEyowCGMqgDUbo3cguzOKqhlS7c1HcZ3XAgVWhHE8Dza3dzYIINrxVdHBtJ8p2m5AyzN/tmwQcOfJxViPYjc5t8bB22As3isENmWU5UVJdIaXavnzMbm1bLlEOoDKzEgBC85uld89fXb0@cGrZ0@rIKZsYvGYwpJ0WcdALn9eo@/DMWZqYDLCKrx8672tDSZyJ65WHqNFjkF/bKJ9zQRYNRDHddwDwsipeFRN/Cy4YStCtX0yqurj8Mvp7I1OXIzLDUGZ020HtkKuWvnlMoZ0xdhXGUkwk9gA6uDAVOT2bAyM51qhG3kFYEC4WzcBihwj/0TKtffu12p6TT2ipxow1lptn40s9pNxCIpn5av5JMNtK7R2fKsCTA6P/5m13a8QX6jbHevcQz2@0/eaHR2399aZu@/1rchDhMJhxL2aHi7V/DlziUyzASEueTmrkMn/@e@K27lKk@iMncTF7P/WO08lL64zU3/G16U6lbgPk5VAtXf1JFgkTzjbpJd0dIXedLCUa@@fgFY9cN6ZfUSO@x726rW1vuetu@@hy1mEWSgjYIbBK2jR7eC7YeadDhFrnJxM8A7kVQzd@@7F55/ClKOfWBAnx9@frj5oVCsV1@3gEHyP4vuefvnir2jln7l1svYfzaYXgpeZrzupw2xfxMfNU4K@auPQGrgKgXOOgkRGHx8uX/mjL0Bacio@oADdkigwDiYl3PMlvqyDvkkoc@H9ICaOPDs7ubb7fuRRqfNZMOywreIq9t46I7eTwJ9zs4tN6MJrt6n1BCp56NWUw3o4gd3601cvPvcqe76FrXoFq6Ky1tPEAYRCBOPgqwO8ESlDOsBViKoSjtYjgoH/1ir2fnYsew1/v9K5uroRns85pysIP5WUgAfOvCoUN/OuT2lnllLBMgo8fMFb21@evbKrUBdTsODLCW5vS2JaHMTqqT6Y3JBT0Ba4fIllPG9jZYXeYZV57HntZtPFjChX0FqMV5hDs7ywZp2rme8NHI1IPwoLLuxp19sNDmSJG62tdnNz@5PpDLYID@9EX4mBhXiotbwNk@UKyIaBpy7/WQE5GXZT7/7G6s6X4eE/f7f7cuup0@991rKr9g8xue3PIhOAmX9ZZ7EIeOxM8r0SEBi52Pcbkf9m2tgYNPsgeba2B8H2ZrDTXN/pbwbru73d3d3@cGOnN9jd9rc3@70G5hunKvWLcAJSks3kj90O79btTYLZTru5Oxy2Wlvbg83d4W67ub6@0dvZHDQ3NoY7LX99fWvQ3unt9j4utaXwlIDBKr6Le0eeAz@8WbgrXePtUtv9Pw)

I tested Internet Explorer 6 with [IETester](https://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

```html
<script>onload=function(  ){document.body.style.display='block';document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:document.querySelectorAll?257:265}</script>
```

In IE6 changing `body` while parsing doesn't remove all the contents of `body`, so processing was moved to `window.onload` handler.
Also, `body`'s `display` needs to be set to `block` because changing `body` doesn't remove `<style>` in IE6. Looks like `<style>` is not descendant of `<body>` in IE6.
There is no need to cancel `html:after` because IE6 does not support pseudo-elements.

`document.documentMode` was [introduced in IE8](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_documentmode.asp), so IE6 needs to be separated from Chrome, not from IE11.
I separated it with `document.querySelectorAll`, which is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196470/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-internet-explorer-6-using-javascript/2196554#2196554) [present](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in IE6.

Answer (score 3):

## 268. [Versert](http://mearie.org/projects/versert), 12505 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x
#  
#
#  
#
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script>onload=function(  ){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test  (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 #ata",_"[];=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers951 6 4>8370::$/  \0Vngt=BFloatk:pext se>ExPrdispsminhar Cr~-<u Uint 22FACw;re-  82:t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIdPMDvM17u5sckn373gHR6AJQAKoJVKGrCiTQbHbMjDdmNZbCK49nHSNprTuSLa@0doS1jvVKDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIkezSKWJBAZWWePJl58uTJk18nG4bX/cUvYvhhR05v3Ok5PvNNz2ct17owXY3tjNljw/Jy2VVJQqhttzPsm7bvFaQY0xmzzUt2YDetFvgx3zk3beud6UJYlrGB63Rco8/8ruHDiwWx2J7Ze99/77Om0@8bdssDyFXGjgwIbA@b58xoeL5rNH3LsSFojbEXds/oN1oGAwjTHbimT@hzDFA0zynOdMg6Y88c1zMx@abpeQ56bjC2ZfYH/rgML3mAMFzLebr9/POZyJuMfW5AzgY9czSTFz3DXlqm25qJoevsq9P9/VnfLPtSdWy2fzN/@ip74XpGz5jFv8a2h75z4M/659h2x7QNltU2texs4DrbcY0bUTaYaxqtttUzNctuMpV1zd7AdBn6sLbjQpX5Zi@fyWfq25OYWhPj5ieBM2hLwYcZbseDQOfCBKcJNTGwzBZru06fGbZ3CSnpm5kJPKLdnGaHJmQQGI298SB2y2SebQ0Gps8DobimS8GQMutZ9rnEue/IdVrDpmV3AM4Eug6GPpXJk5oQrcwGgoc1dLAYUYGDQRZOnL4ZrQsPmBdy7Q3MptW2mpw45sg3bQ/K62nMgrq7tHo91jJ7EGGCvZlinsOGXsSr0TO6WlOTkLiYCuuf95jFmoMB40FQDMjSfibPzL7zxmLvILzX9dho0Gee1Ydgv@m026bJ3pmDLkRn/ZbUciQGn@ZgpmTh27IJMLYJpds9@gbo5iM57TZkrcUaETjIB@WZSmzYDpDPZbbR59zQHIyp9IAmjNF2HA39W47p2XGfXTruOWuYTQOLjYl5ZqdtDHuQotXG6gA@sDzWd@AJlWgzyBZE9pEWiBsTk@YWBJMJqtccQMPE6nWQXaCug1q@dA3gD9cT9ehbfeAOy497zDQ8CyUWRPFMu0WcMQhlmQOljVY6u7Cg4QEphi7h9kyXWJ/wMiwFoDRCXlUuXcsHjsBSbLMj03DZqWuaCc6nptc0Bsil0SQhMQdT8LEgGjHm1la8crgfBwblMTRjAAzprp5@5wvJYFqJLdeL8C3JclGqPN9jV8tn6OYyE5h44CpGgpU@MC99dmbCd6Q30h33WgKsElClx9LOwE8b6gAyqPqQwbSBTnSpF1lt0IskzLZm6iDSbDhUC2oDhAD7KkUlaw5dF6X7hKjGORS659gdoCcU1h3avMrXM1AFwH8tL8XMCxN5gNeRc0kUPu0Ch8A/gEYkC@9wiKDQ5UBTFBQN0vWc3pDgIKbnY3sEqkBUxHjQZl@xtmH1MAqEIyqea9f0gDkxztBuYc33LdtsaSzIBkkdF9riBSRnAFLygNbQj8gWyhQAQ0U4VFQM@vibv9PqdADPdrPpuC3Brl8BszepazQos9C5MWRYxzZ6lC2AS2HqPDokcGH0rBZJOcMeiyQoE5TqpTPstRg11EsLmlzXAGFrgoBo@iZncmfoQx5TrG@cc4locc6FgveNBlQsJUBpU7FV9ngXaqkJzZx4Ru0P/XaeqYMKi3vpV8qjgvJo6cyEzCW0xMpyOt0pAsNpK@QFb/HbOOer7amuwvMNz7Fa0mDsdx07y9Qmk5slZ2DaSnwKRzwVdxvxhIaSWkkUrVJTa1t2S4lvAS@WIeF4otgsNatWoVaciR5NEtBcIhpsrqbSTMgoaqhRXKT7oFxoIMm@UoUrEuZ4dSQ5BmsRbyTMrN8F94iR6oJ86SCDgBzSvJ5pDpSMpidQTCDc3HJjwLySzuAQBS5YtWQ8Fk9Gi04YoKRTBcXGemo5KLZ6gy7qG0AU2xuAzHWRd5sGcI@HnZoPKl2KNYivqScEyUIy8dKMg9RugCAN@IiaJG9yGF9FQSkwTJrQdEs2W5GGDEIA2rLv3ZDGPQe1A8oT9jwgOmxM1OhA1UBkXpBtXhCeEvlMF@ncBoGC2Bomy6sNCxoBNjeQ6YLnI2UD8NUshwFsvJFEZE/fGGOvxlWDSYPBPs1gfRAP7pg1TZQ5IHxM3qFgIkNqfx7ovcxps4yazeWm29iNJua76W31uyCk36VvbUlY@GhjQkHD2qBm9wy7MzQ6IC8cG6IYzaY58IWggpJ4Poii2f6GPFXReWpeV1p@PJs2dSKBejRJA4U8rz3RFRooXYTaroJOhqofHwuwluWCWIKefCZ1ALiYSVx@jSBTGXgtL8hCoAEAk5kjszn0QaoBA192rWYXeBZzZ3O5yDuh2eTBK5o6SHa1HSaNmdHLD7OSlg69MBsLUahYozfxQOeKqMpTHlT5UY/bMRtefw5iJ8widAQRXy1taMB7d@DsO7YzBykQMkSLINMhvB5AEztBpRg6rkDtosYaasphFUGdgdSAlg/81/X9gVeAfsLyu8OGBpySPnXHB/6hjcyS9t2x5Tvc3eg5DRDLHrTPdJBCujlsWKOZApFfWIdvPOkCFLC2x0rQc78dAtcp8bYHApP8dxE4EiST4CYU/FcGQALSgFBK2yNRvA9C5WRsNxV5iinlFJOx7coJcGDEkDRfoPI2nc034DWbSwSLZkZLI1Tac5vkUCM6KaJHcMqW9GCqaPfMo/RAluGnbfQ8E572sNfD16HNpZzCdYUEu5IePADRplByVn/Qs5qWX@eh7OFDoVOwJRjjodrURp0pAXEeiMG0BgIFYET3w6E13zkhZVdJQEEeXE8lbLqu4/J0/a7rXDLyQDApStRdp4/Snb0khQs1aBjWWjYO70VfSl2pMVeFCPtU0pfjce2NY9nKVXxpaSleiJehx1xaegSuLXQ9QlcSXI/IpZIL4TR0UYwUuTC0SjHQrxa/rgaYR4kaNocR9vbvrIFiVAuF1VrKqOrimcVnAugMPQZAq/gAPPFEqYTOREIuX0JBtUZ7uvS72OudNF1rIIjwhXFh8HdBhVUiA1Sc4@LAoIjKy@006Zdc0C5gMNDsKm78rJo5q51dnbWSZ9fxFMZOFI1SAwoF6Sl9reM6Q1BDEtW1gqrXEonqKigfjVI8E19RlLwKwzgYiSQ@yyeSBqe2EjehN1TOzuJAVEGfarPrEr5RKptIhKSCfKDCA7q2Eteu8pB@I1FLJOMQNxFPwdCtFI8DZZpIBI8KjW1pikCHx19ywuwmkxI1bxiV4vdGdwp@OOidjn40fPcOZRfH0Qg5rDc0uJY3EADpAzuA1TBwZtAaBDXaDOXoVBqfO20@KtrFn8rTfckcUW19frhfOS5RMl3DOwedQu0gbBp0ZaCK29JAGvSGLVOaBwNiA1zNSU5w7gAT7zSbTHUYgalNnolId9FkC7CBrCHF02Fqrz9dBK8L@d2dKgMhIX@KeZv@0gyyxMHn5ilMch8k9u7J06kpsv456BOs6fVQ@VZdXgB4Ta9wzxY9wjFGgR3QGM0GBRN4C/TLVjgXYDu2irIwGM450YT4hAhAkB9qW6hJWFMwiLhtjWBIHMP5FKH6o8aK2v@uY8Pg1NRekjSUGQhynK0ytbn6/xFXpLSmN2mdoOmDc9AzmiDvp9GdyewMEIIESqfnhySKNxDPDg5oHH9XGUGVaho20q9l0Th1aHldJC@MJbAXcNtAVRyk4uQOUe2ANUHL7QClzZHl81ErtPATjPLE8JQEjpO2@TgDuQx1ZMxUMHNHCqzThBG@CboyhvLpElaxLyzXsZHIWgVQgygqYh3MIJ9HXmCj7e2D7N5i@s5DDhS74a1HaBvFOkvcpgety3Z6TsdhKwCArKlpnLEPbJzhhFGObwygRVnviEDbHQeG@tM8aJrhnOn6ajjeNBAyTfDaG@gF2PxCTwAWlPnk4LsVUEP0XCYD@Q/eMvQJCxnBMltG9GyyCYBYBegh32BNftccdMfuFDt5jpg38WnykBomn8kyQIWEXIkW/o6iRhs594F2HgS1Ate8sldoTICTd9Fx9VTpp7QV3myghLEZb/QNSDGF9EaFT@oXBddZekpuhVMFarvv@Eb6Kw1ENP5IqCGrFpO9dHwpnlZV/JUpiGXLLN0yL9IopSaYRxWzORf3yDSbaQzFzo0FjrnkCQIXkOYMPjb9QDH5M6BBGHO2/J1kEgU75S5Mm2caOvnT7tCUzGbXYfIZDDGiJZOhg@jCWFkFyoMCiOOSMJpYEZJ8ZwjDupbZs/qWf0Bz9j0bxy4aCW8NpZYI3QV5M0FwZJmgkPMJh0kng/Pqkz7K7nD4Y5DkhBWG@BonqWu20isTbM8cx4Vxpcd0mlPIhqTvi4C04w1amj8CBDxWhfp3L@jnnx/uVepH26dPSumh56Z7VgNkRMus92Ew24PmsOCDecMZwgrwjmU7fQtKFKB8d947dhyfKw@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@hpwDMEyCuI2tuI/DcRM9wBXlqbRVEpZCf88IXRxKYr/TMNSK/xDXoSPmudJ38L/x2e8o7S97nKnZlvYn3KnnzFejptV9R2BtBc4FDfGuEj69cz8V3I2gucIgvx/Hhivd8dDMh80BDZOuEDFfI5@KaCZgDGGLaIEzRVfVJWJ7CFi2pi7TmBi@MFOLeJNx8tbz@hq9W1MViOXIzbyCnoIk9dUB/fmrhvH17qsVI4Qj8TJKDaYTpiaRJSHayTMLUi/nrO3IUERcGln3u0MA5dNUzmp5DLCGK/nnvZsw2DDXoZwr0RqZuhvD@q99o088cAOx0Z2fmKICmPUXXD12tkT6mB06AzsvB9FTuVPINsz2EUVC6YdnovgNM3cwTZLvRsBaBAiVw80HwnANWYMdDGIlmtTVND4a9uHQCMpvPw54eHBJgw6BB3PT8P5sivj90fYglnv/1ey2ohJtV1DXGNBYMHXXbvCT@aC@sMREVX@hnfu1Oen0iDLnuQtk0cMnV6IWO@aip9lW1a7h9HHKJ6gYGxR/ghFt4jeecz8UEz/mJFBgReXqdgdlWnzXnQBPszJIIT4wG2T3HaBEZ@FDYMimSi5XNq8Ec8UFhROGBnmdRQnNWLthkq4DfHfpD/ou7A@6qRmuA39uaqIDM5IyGboKKbDQs85ZKd43zYctRQdOjImPG1ufATkpPk3Vqu2ecc2cdnfOLzwvoWp0O6BPiuQjssgtjGxqUpi/pcRdfePbQG6gNqCwfGg69UVPo35KC2@O/i0AssX8udCymmtWjn3tUeshcxC6g0hGhcUuTGiGaNUPmntEY41C9@@lchgmSggMyp9RMJjOr2O2Fa7/RrUiL42NfSfE3N@fH5pupOEnmDa/SfBOVyieQqcxiW9UdFQsdl9U3emq2FXEulOjB1PHENQeU5m3UZs/wgLV8UR3mBVQf/dzG7tgzNWHY5U5ctzD7JDvBFoBFq8lCbIlW3XR6lodNu7dIgs4uwE3SxO1s9BOZkrbmEbZFOpPXVUPXfLngNH1cyl3AaPeQcnwVFdepI5yjOYuI1nQu8btQteg6Fyb/nd/RvZubq3tILLVHLGE15/YoreZdnIrbgehnPh3P5@bLb/bm@k@3gWCKIzpAuydfe1bP8dgJ/d5Glo4L0fjvfI6OUtAybJXWg6Lu@dFEpgZME7OsC@rV6HWc3nq@kzbgZ2HlD9029gnieV/pF0ovXb9begX6kWPr4rlQ7J@n3fO76o6WJlxctI84b@mB54kwsSi5uIAwksCdOPMLt5/JU0wtzcfLiyrAbXYvjXHw/CV6lkXUDXqWwZj0bVD/MMJmHhy@y3XwXya1tdtTa91PPN1Au3FXISKVe94zoSOj3xtVyrIZ/RNj6JnM/YVVuzc0h@ZcWXXYeGPi/vZbRiH3z1RGFGNZzHbijBDOdYZQ78T48V65xj4c324VMEbPgkZ@p6YzV94NQEcf4JD7CBxH6LgZsWMPB1OVOzWKs49vp1x3ELRspzWVSQz5VImUv1ufmlLkPZO@tw6u@GAQ17ZKa5lMRug3kfnrqZfbBl2rYdw3Fv@dSph8JilPYHE2xI0456cxmUqFqrfOPRUnNe8nnbKLZgQIeHMzbVu26Y/xd1GVzJO2DcfpfUoVgtBtWai/gVaKCz93VeUN3UjsBmOTuQ8PZ04a7UWzHrxDEqNToB4OvG/jhujU672qWcUla2ilnZnX2@eBIhO5d6UC3TxNLvGtE73FiqeYUdG1vLZxa4vk6qzTMHsGf4zW127Dt6mt3oovVFmEnkxrW7gexlfAJiuqsRm5NRgDsawWDHK6Zt@k11tGB0brzdALHguBRg5@5wRrtN64KN7AAkFh4@/UaltElfIdG4ZlvuF2TBzX9HBVXPguEs7BrPpc4h70jY7Jz1XdJj0nUx24dZiPBifO@ZMeBb7rrAnR@NaP21kBGtO5OfaC51yEz8ZNqM9h/@6pupl236SNSnc1dC09dzHhDl3R7jpdu2t2@U6g8G1R8wCO9PmJuNsKAfnvdJuM5FN0l1KUsj2n17sPZVE@cmnpOO25eargOa0WRP0kvGOjAQHicecUIPT1RCDq9Be1m645hC7Lc3xnYKr0tgi0h5NF/HeRFA0Wd37ZWahbZwiAIsHzl8V/59i0Yzj@YECP@qA39OiHoqp0vG5eVe5TMvfhCsvn244435odp9HsWndlqWEavm2dp4MZIf5668h2EKGCxdQ99NZ6FhDPHWvIDaVo@Ak@DhZVqZhc4t1W6JhfxwW2O3TdMVLCdxzm9ZzLiXyY3j8RTuPy1Qd0LMqBWBmcE0zaAO6sC3aQ3bIEIhYSFzIYKeGocKtmBhQWfeGM0tT2zkjrWF3lP4v0opnyU6Yi67efMiUqtj3Q5KAVmbkF/yn@mVqMnttZ2d1hx7sp7viEfQtULPyZW9PbHTzTPFPRvFKhBzJs8VhE72wvjdu34VmHmhuat66u5G5dXiE4vacajgWPOjygDocLp8161sDjv0xtZ@cqDDeXkG9CjecPm0X9tMw2XwtB112aXt9x8RARqBRq0zW9Jk6lo0Tm@hOXPrbTAcms9tgEOICdW4Sbq9Zzqz/s8dSvn5sdA7dXPrVwp2VvDlcA1tnF67uQfmdoeNZ3ho5vzsU3u4B9F7pnRsdqPpmifIAsoKjYg8cfU2yPXjeJf9m1PDq/EThumXNCJuNsi3xWB31/3mhtZro@PBh9@7RKRFESe7@ZesCCPeKhAxcMMNyYm9a8mXhnQOPGMblum4S3fJqZFc@5XDV/E8BtyV8O@4OhJx7zU6d9OtEp6v45@XuXFohF9S1IY9Y1ev78aezIzCzoXKKTnDgXaeHftXpOh303n2GgokGnjUr5HIbbge76yPChRdhzGJjSvudCKU56qC4v2FvgCXOVqZZt@bdP8Pi@AWOk4ImF4Z0NnkJMP8Vf7fGnYlBP51Pk6a0aDPTt42YPD8V/6kiAi13gwhM6tI7O8Nx8lO9FMuauQBj0LrZ5GR2v3broU8Au1bGHvoq7/G/rU9Zv7VMKbJRfj7AGU75TefYiEeUQ2v56lx5qwkBw6PXGE9fCjQczjGfZoKwtlsXT0MFoYs8kkwbHtFHzjjjbAzw9RSJ/z5k34jkaQ@9z7yETdCDD/p7ZxJXHO9N@7jwD1Q26sgEI3f6xiVsGZmTJ/IgY7anTNHpAn9adyZwQ2jl9xWRwbQzMBtRvb@Kar4vNQ7xn@MYC3YkmDmkEGLru5BWr1zDdNzQjGHEvGtROZ@iJOaJhyGKG4a1Q9ZtNrnDjtNxUG5ld2/EGjmPzXxLCGXjoz24XNtA90M/9V9w13L881fvNHaRNl/bwgm83MVv84N6i4rpmw@nxXyzCAnFgW3xzgeFappd@atnDEfkxFXS3@cMcvo03o23gNIfXhcZ2acEYO9zdi5vV@FZhb2YkBSrxheHRkv/8Mc3UTuL77yrqGm7TwbUz4fjElbPIkbA75Hi4VZpvTWhApYxAoBnNYWBX4I6s9vqNPv0sHJNEavrYbOCRuwadH/WN0TwlcvromPCcObwViDRs@OtMOYJRT@Lujmx2yDZNcWtAPyTQL@eySZDcc8tsvjMSd8jSsBXRXHLaoBHt3IY0vQkO1Jyeqfpd3GOZ9v1FAuO5dT5s3WOtK1hAGfZNXLOeXrlZyFSO1yWOcOav0ocC1zXF1m3cJQhNP3Cj1FW3F7Isoof/w50v0tAx19fX8AT/cKR2QJzdvS8AMj90bfG4D9sdOZ7ftkaHAzTj5LiL5AsWKwdR4MGbA7pWFhUC6tMe9vh8Ryeyo6vfovEdaINtB1w9EuG@qZr2hUomjkbBcqVrBHZkFtbh7OZQ/Y7doZdeuB4IAerAo2d64B0dPD081QaefsvMIW74G1o9XN2jrAR@UEByLZ6iPqG9avdcrFDhgatxU4@5uMWq6KBrNEzfSBsLBzsYavrzNb8np8@eJicnl5my23WdvpmIBu@enKQg7@yLk7nB0dj7wOJtZ7Qw@kFF1xNzePCFTWuCi@TenJQWYTo1YcgKHPWEH6K9U2tqOgOzdToemF9Bl4iy17tn8usLC/ncuLA62JTY5kJCUWtjm9r6WgDyFQzH8VDULXwijkWRBafQ1oeXEgf2wM9yhVEATwvMkYnTjdRZBedswNNoNoc4rwa51BgBKoqRTCYSkoj1xLlkfbR1hJE8OqR7bg2KLBM4MZdd0EcIHs0UKGzZYFslls1kWCJR5BY/gHmhRQ7NImtbAeptz7M6NmQhyAEZa0JDLtwOlMdg0OMHeKtVtnw1KmQK@jUrMbkgs1qN5xg/lEhlNCBLS8c8enXZqJWW46oaX46f2QWWiYfgZg8G@3PBjSlYyCw@RIZD@nIrbA6ZUAupWeSGaqATRiNQXcNu9UwmGBrK73JzK9yWzylu3v7LP2wJ21hkA65veUYPCILm7aBtdZ3LRzzdgFyDgYG2tRDHZRcn5jF1dXebeZc4yc5NYkF1vdg/zQtDO8KWHrwc8anXMBecc3D9Fw8N@5wxeG7CA6Ai4TBWUCgYjQ77Nqh/Lb/raezEovPAQ3dywkdYGLR9Fxd5Wil2wFom7pOlY960ptlznHM6@oU5@cs/5OaF6LC3OIQbJE9mxSIp4plunWz6NJvOEHIdIHlnuo4AUZDIRtMf4g4CsmpH/gk8Ak12j4Db1cDqDyXDTf/sbp8wtcLiaC8PrXQUrbayvH38@VfVTK30gfXT5n/9XjpxJQgnf6ZurntyigUgxWtkrGhwDoInoXEmL49knmB4Et4Sbf2S1wfa@uNMhofhAx5znEHQbHAAQ4bKQm4UBkAUdFM9B@Z/@mT0jRjWvCTzP3Tk0sYelYwOetDA4DVBqHmrKy0rQ76orZ74LAcJogklA1zcTBydDUdTNhhlecTeM@r1YASj5zLwxgnZQ@tJ/dJOcIpiNXq6Jb1nNoa0w/siq2VzJSrOcr20VSYXaEgOWjGrvjobZTPq2WijUoMxmSDq2dnos0z2a6C640Ksh2lseZXne1fLWjnz/r1njJksX8eL/DQOiInlq6ODo8rJ6fbpixOohetAtO3zM3mBrEEuomO2XadH9uGALjg4@gT5E75NxCBaIE0kpOiBSAIVtJZVeZk7I6JpKvYd0efF98xI@E0AIdPaFpPCngG4wCBmQ6ph4YcDtHLHRFxhqYu4zML@AxtQSBg88zRHlhKpZFYCYqlArHuSii0u7CPudx@K3YnldrI9mguCFAvTq4bhvIhzSXD9Kyn3wPC8v3@5OZbby00wt5QbQEPfIM7@9sHTF8eV6WhBJ09St7SZEyeBuXDGlsYHWIFpMjLAISLipoCSzGSKwF9FZ8YNpJr@pQnFEsKx2eeRiUMp/7I0YUygTAlt9NaEFqIolAPUb1ARmT2oDKOfSBaDPjqC7ooXMRQC@3KIOsi4JgvMMbI1q@EnKAZiFeQKmt4RCXEhr@NeVP1JBS0Oi4Z99NDjbW5BVxX2Oh6D/0ivFLiyNTZiojvTa0xlWfj2TLsDBQ5gE0XeR7FlTgh5meddDvOLNkIhT603Bq3D0QEcccAXeumeMfACZTDGnju@WWBvhw4ZEQmESahfkHlag5v0parlhmrJOAkMAED1Dfotwnewf1JC7YyrZiTfozw3tLGjAiBuXVcc8/ddtELNz19zM5ec5I6wqBh0lTSX5QkLaqGW4LELy7NgNECV0EYdpweSEksjCo4Wmsl8DNvueaCTtKD7Bg3Fx64WlBONToXyo6GqzeQY8KQWqowpJksI65VuWtiDrvQShyeveeRlgiPMXgRnfGtJVYFyHcsOzDEX0D4zTeMUmO8OcdNnOX4jSpCFArnUrt/vRQDn2Bo9M9Mff/N3uH3RMx/cPxLuUWYH3n5dvLXB/RtBiK7D2z8L37Lw9mP@9iqNVXbTqOIkn6F9jIXnaIE5H8s3CoaCITBMTQUKqxyr@6uDI@Y10d4xVmgfBpmTukIxE4xTmNUHzrigikZwnsKkHid4lCqO2IC5gElQx0G1htIz3ZqC9vUK6TRmHJfnNNp9a474jhgyt/d2iGZmQRNLr@fW1/Q0ZFK9CBCSBaAOHgbkCBOJAghG6cIalF43mmxra4vJXtPomaX1ImeQ9LLxalV@HWZ0GWAlPlqoMogDUSYxIKwsoinLRlJPYFTszeJ6HAVby@H8BiqhQg4ASaC3HdgMAZ3TEaQCZrbNkU9q0zgYBYHUtp2IfekAkQqIOG40hjrbJicH/HBOOdJKtWg1yC8RjCZVCvI8jq2@Ymf@mV0TRnEZcN/P5vCvDe5/MsdSLucstIl000SrMmtgFUvDHp/YDk7N70NumZJNZ1fT@noiwqGyQAX5xfb@HlBCCweJ0TStN87A296tHHxxeHRyw1QXQcZnweIsXt5KnqlaqloLHfEw39NE3dlPnzzb2Q9IGc3VZHIcISa7nWezOS@12ZwuSP0lP0t5M20KuJGQnrkvYppZU/fp1MBN7JPQdARwlx/lupGqkri6rta2ymd27Eby7@eZX45pK8hc4DrzyPhyfDabmMXwqoVTvGrB0wJDATpaCcDjo75zPrE5IDwiARw8wAISQNLSAdQi4QkZOOQzQBPjOFl@14NHoo/PEpFR3DBHEcjT4FYIbFoTW47CiGHX8Lo9qyFBB95Cw57cBFFgYyc0XqR5g57lKwmJpkBKqAaBEFPE3RCjwkijNX2FTDATrhS7zS5igC8hQSMAfPGjoddlR84gMre1ZwauY9BG2N6QL/ia7IthH@Da9Dg2UcSaoJ@oEBkIFQ@zykfV0LKEWcRREk1PQnpVNI4oCq71WzlllNC65qhldUCAK4kUtPTPdFCrQsMNWGgylWjHQcZxCn@OR@iiJP0k65ijCXKjamiW3TJHCpp7KtRAP0X/@OXLi3hCvsEDZKJzNzDqN2OrM2iIhi9axMTO5Uxj2wwvhJgxprq5iSaz0AYFVAukeOK7T8EJ/ZPS7hsDpgzJiKzHNEavyplipzzfTTC1zO3Q2CyZpFE1PCgAtGYEbZOLGIcpOA@ppEtQO@jr2S18vLMGrKprWg3clEiCLeOM2i505TgXlZBglARRCoS2hHXLCpgjzr0a5zyIg@ESWbVjaEl1TjDZPqVZYwdpQaVm5YcRa2CTFsipurlZELUxLWo2GbDFTSmvpQHtHBESaKlAX2FSAKiGdwPgJRK4ogRi4fGXpm2bQCDgmb4BfbAxBCZzE6ngMpjUxJY8pRDjWXwibBRARqdtzFfiVz3cdrCcLtLkTPEa@tTXZ9iptkW3Ok7/j2ktXbxSlnulcRoUnURZWe6W9OTqSjK5bK8oyzZ29Q8f4pzO9TJoEnUNhkgjAFKXe4ki8DNoHqVlu7hsbCnLrVJ2hWLAKwzSriDCBy@tXS0b1@nlh9BTp8DH5Y1XWfbITGlG0/RryB@2kOV0CnjmCq060k0wmPyylUxiHrTlOmbgQ/rsJEky@@wkTdNHRaGNpjt90dxmpGpYEzfuweEEFN6iokGwZ1Gwi6Mh9QB4YmF@dV7YAt2DJ/wlnr5jtOHX9KLqvzwdcn/BIuRdnCzIcaOw3E4sEHCkABHxNWUkEiBMfvGLmL7OZGX50fpq7yIZz2WK8KMXN1iOfbZ8ll2Lsdhjw/BhyJ5euTrby3cumNnOrr9V1arV1t7Wjs6Pjr4ejRNnSjy2e/hK1tcAdINt0ve@nw2WXfBhn/aJxVbSUiy9oj/cSKdfv34NKi9@qmWtHIBotURVjdeqyobw6Jc3NlZS6/mV1PHjeB3yAsVNKNls4oRZVpqdWQOv1YKv06V7mZQY/7BHjzA9cMA/E379UZuco22z0xlWjDH3t2JDfOz7Iu6z7758@RIdL@nD3h2L@DGOUaCLFepGLkaZzGayf/mnS9epq6P61l9@v582l/BxiI8fXT9D94me@2xp6bOdnbW1FBCOu4@@e/TN9vb22l4qd1TNPVpTM0tbf/HnS0vZ7FY2vVTzPL0Wr55/LWcza7L2l78frx8dfcfzsO7ws8p0cOJvHr46y@XYOXsHn/M2w39yv2tF3Aa6G@132EGCslwiYROP51bjJ6/iWD/vYrqux8b0V6eiLTG9/Gjjv/3k8G3Mj5Wz6ZcuPP3Y29h6Psad4IC31eDtIlaObSHY@nVsnC6VSuDc@G//HuKXvwA8GDLegp9yLsC1Po6V1RJFeR8rr4NDz2Yh3f/ne9@TYuURZKJcPthn2XJ2RbCJnn@oPySX7XdBwTiL6fm1w8f0apmPD7O57Ba6bRPvs@nCcBSFjK5nz5ioPF1UIRZXx1/uwbrgxjp1YiwAndQ5CziKvYwRfwCDEI9wt/AgtuEeL2fhXp4ZxspGci372C6@jHymXn71n2O8Nmx96fHrvXR6qwz9PH4KhcdnddHI0mwjLzvOY5z6K7KnwreIPyNHVR0Ah@8Zear4EeSL5UupOidR0MaCEDZ5Y1GvmKAkC5vTLwFXwc9f/V9/9dO/@gn9/ZS@/1mKBZuC1OpFrRx8gH/ksitfnYlX@xl7xj@2Df/wDV7RBz3AZYuZyVj4KZfxh/7FG7noOeMnQsrhC0FMoiyEY4G8onSl2Id0mmELYBdBYR4vFZbyhfVCNl0PikfF4Dknx7NI6SblE@V5BJ8l@KN/@ISv@LtEPsKbQG5@llj5Pp@5HYAUq8aqtRpv0@VoBd3@OdaQ6TTxVo92KRdSTAUplUweA5MywdvwOUve8XkBX02ri7e0NsEak2K/8k9ZYrEr@NSS6vV1VXuVLBbFP2h3xfANP9wFWatdq@rWq3IyWaUsVssir/E1J77uPN5SWa3MC0C/Wv3VFqBPblW3Ss4ufTXiEbX2qlzdmsYBny21Vn78OImkfQwIyss1BuMKqI3rrevydXXr@nprC/636PdaPMH3euvGPz0mnwUwk/Aa1v9ZNV0@S4tGWa7Bu5Yuo4@WPgNHGZ4AV61KsSvkHFatkam9klrV13M1lVEDWQHhlS7oK9nVdG702XolCzLAQ/CsLKdX0PEe@0rQdjalGI4bNvnwYZM8Xn/89v/A79nHb/8tvELW8E5DCm28xb@n7/DvrY9/p038O36Lf@z0Hf4d@/j3rIF/Rx7@nb7Fv@0G/p328U@KlRgDDW75UaaXucjo5/o5OCyWAQW6m@nqLeh8WMZkmXFmzDJ9R2@By4S/DLisTJtlOixjZ2xdh0Bw@Czjo6sNjw78tQGLC39WJoPIMxcMUulhl0ZWq@n5vs4SZ1KVxV@boHZpupbR1q16Lbc@eFuN14qx9NlZmuuiLLtWJCvl19eM1euV53v1ehrbw9kz53Dyf3jYj77e@t8/dJ4dOn0H/g8PD5@dgUgrJx8n1cfwKZWTW@LxKFYuPjorqMjLAVfH0luPzsqrKrrXk8CoWfRLfuJnghGe5aUzCcbqL19eFqnfLV5eFC@L5AhfuaMuAAQYd0CsouivwQfinb1MUx97CZ8Lwktv6LyEwMDFHemXl2eoUcL4IfwHckRffwX/1v@//p@9YEq1loBGcHW9pdAngX@JxNX11bX4LScURbwoW/CHHvCOUa6uy@gkoCtwVZVELXF9zf3gV0lscYRlTGOrTJEngCA8YmGalC7/UX61T0ybf87ioDjByFoRy4JnZ6NMJlFsgE@4NmC8pxWmRJH23iw3cFUQRpN6giBya8WivsLd2bVssbgmXjbyxWJeuJcVZfPmp5x5pK@DdrC2lkgUixkBC@PGYuAEFKZnNIvYyIuxBGaWt3wlg7OTdD9JXC7IDx8q4kabR4NB4uFDfTPz/n3oVa@3LLdeR//V9@/luozbdEqbOXjP5N@/B6ETTziu8tzhC8SKqrPPsmVKYdNxoVQbEMz0dHaSZtfwDN93lXfWICXjrlRPTpBN8UzGcc/iP//x979/Fi/hxg3yXdMRAabCcltb62vl8voauNfzUHB5me8EUjrJTT1xvZyWeXGZvByPiSA9v5Eg3@s4hrPYFntUhobq4YddXceo/thaLqE0xmbiCnwCP31zk3uytXUln9wUf6WlBCuvMPFXrVZXk2srGyuPa6Dx3PygUC1eGaV4Oh2/Ll0ZBZzFui42xd0VeF7MePhwdROImc8Uz6R6fW/7dLuO117iGj10iAw9SUJLuP46cONVmnLMbdaqWLDaWTxeKD6matfzORaLFwWcGgdpz/KbVP6Y50lWGw@OjhCpFAt/V2IDpm@sQicLfaw0oJ1SGxnWwsVmlznt9hJ4QrWxBu4L8MxeL7jq49Jxe61Lq2UuSbGjp9u7ldNUFvSVWHZ/ezeVPXmxE9PxNTd5x2AWW0WP48r23uELiHH0tLJ9Uvn84KvKiyPw96Q37wzTNMyhaV7Wh8PLt3gdhFk3B@A7@dTNpuUZb94YA/rAkIXL5Y8/@@HHn/1PH3/vxx9/74cff@@nP//2pz@E7x/C98f8@eN/t5nD359/@8/@4OPv/h54/mf4/if4/unPv/2t7/Evvf8ZfP9LxO/PxDcCx78S4Pr1n3/7k9//@be/8dvw/Zfi@9s3v7/5p/O/P/3B4i/G@8kf3A7z438P3z/iuALYH/8u98PnDfjf5XC/8dsf/8V/4P9/If7Q@Xsf/8Wf4Y94@ae//Rf/5eP3/2M2m/@Lf/Pxhz/@@IOffPzB9z/@4Ecff/CPsx9/69/omejPH3z86R//9z/5o//@J/8L/f8h/f7Rff4//vY//ev/86//77/@E/H9U/j@B3D96V//R@DVv/3jn@H/T/74b//Tz/D/f/9Xf/vH/@vf/vq/JsfvcMf/@y//Hf/9m@//8G9@8M//5vvfLvj94a2/397D/9t/AJ/75/M@eO5Trk/1@faXys/fhxqTVIAH6NoNlgX1dWds0tTFZ6OC9BmLlVfwA9K4ms/mkyugea5sboJIrpH/FoIwCdrpT//Jx9/6NWD/fwHI4O1/hjf45y8Q9CN6YV9/PRXIkjQdoia//hoDxQDy6yjUj8DjfRr08Mzj9wDxNQXzDwvBIN3/jcAAjgmwAG46AwSDuz25/8@//ee/TwFhXPT@tSmUmcA7Cr2M4O@Dov4I2/2kNFHoH6Ho@Piz7338/X/88We/8/Fnv46dg7q2mdpOQad@@3wvAObuAYeA6/eBA0AdB5Aw4F@SsuBY2sI5SklPvn4NuV8CFwy2VqTcKrxJepncOrohYhLeCMlolMRf@JfWNhm@gM@IfOHJkhC0k8Tr2JPSqARhBIr3uDN0lvPgNcKJhhLgxUg8Tqqeh2EMG@0QFohZSh6z@kppxCMm0aNMGJBtJPQ6lvWsnMyX9iDB0miPIS5EnpRew/N1qZwvjcqI7gNlAXAkdyBJgMJr4pOj8gd4LxFOgJdGex8gK/lSMlnOg08JC5mk1FJ1SlPPUeGo7ElG5UZ/xnDX5aPH0GRkPS/ziRAgJRPQ@JucQCMggEP4WXJFFIf@Ayd9VzA@1NOI6MP9ePgj9Kb4AgDwqipu1oOvqmJuHkPwiKNKUrLwSHIMQLkk6U8BSvAgZSgpJal@k/QC6UMePu2zhaIC0WFxlpeXwbVVllfl@iGMHmGY5p4XPN9wcTGRVMgCk9c3ZfTGnU98T@fyEQ0zV/ZW4FeH/8oS7WOmshRXpOU4zmHEedYgLTW56qw5MV6MoIz0tkJFSBIg@wxC8Pv4MbiBRvSc@OEcA/0npVcxicWo7qGxpPgvPLQS@UeaEnm8KknJyTvOPIoYmpbSUinx1OhJHppwaBQqntoyqYyMj3hoyZrp62ssISl04VkCa6hpkjImPfM6O84IRhspWU7p67gMlRCTNqeFLLZWqVLIwO83TqFQ@qCvbUjwpPchXrwmrgADvsHr57WtLaz/8pVKM0voBJV1XSqXxQo806XySeUUwE8PmZ7NaAxGKldrG9m13Fouu7q@ntvI6mvrm2vrufwqSNb1TC6b1TfX1jbzmxvXIbUeg3BKFVYaua3yP7rx@R/@0bzPfF/8SOWv2UijyfRrqdwr8Z2gy7gaL59l5CJNcxEtl6uZFP5lV1fhF/KZ0nMbtaWl3pWKxT6j7YdXuN8BsipdqdjxPYAPkx5I7AF4wQfSwPVIJnaQHBwWxW4BvD@V7xiQ9RwwMtTDGXAyRwc1enV1FflKsaXvftdn5TKMONSDfSkGbbDLgvVx1WppXY2uPW0NXZNCO4ztHXx1cHJw@FzbOziBccA3LLua0aTY9fV1O1zVoVeTHR4eSij8YGi3qmP86yYbDocU2oD365EhDaKf4mD6I2WzanZVXdVVfRX/73Bk8f/@8Fn4z@IvxFrNSvzYZA/P8wTzZpvYgqUtbgik7Nh4ZLwUXO2qAHWvWqXg0vtiu1StaR7UR7GlNZzWWPP8MYz6WpY36BnjUrzRc5rn8SDQwst@8ARbaSntpjXcqqy0E4@y6xuFJdxGRz6MKW0Gnjn0fBX4Elxus9DSgrSfQfVC1Gwhu5673hKGvsqQccxBGdO7Etko2DB8v8YNqgWjDeW9avKNHQU5m8vL14/7Zssy2FkGTz9dzQVbX5evAzhICIeJOHhX@njNBm5zLmTOMokFcTMQF/JH2ZK2hEmRMq3LV6GF1vD2wWptKzA2UpY@fPgwoq0whQPbF3tismt59GcSiqWH0N8/1Lkztz5xZtB5ioZhnkOVgFyx2VPc2u477NThW6h3zOYCiN2uQZcx7roOjKR/eZgdwz7nQXsWt1ARBj0x0ES117f87gKIF4M@nlc03X8wDJV@AzKIDMQBduDH7TnOPIAN9uJoQSmfhQalcPsMWZQC8OODz5@cRp6nle3dJ9I62zl8vjfzyAmgHHta2T8NXzd4aBA1F6L4pvL06eyreECnVaSpkyWW28Dts8GLzmKGb8ipulytFaGl@teg2uWLLXv4SH/4UN9aXz96CtTcBMB1tlbOr25kCoXlNIO28BWUrbRD1jHOCwPcluuZ5croyMU2BfS3u3j3tvtB3RqyFyQ4cMrjsuiaoPnkswV/WXqGm3Y3dX4CzfIkOgiKt/3hzZ6@hBYsWs6lTYfrGr2hyYYDttATHuiFTtfqdKFrvnQCAKlhGAy@n/qB@NEJF6DZrR4@T4P8boT05oDjLhGrzTKSxgm0mc/lN1ez@VR@M7@W09dzuZSeTekb@Y1N6BQzel5fz@c29VR@bXN1DXpuCM1tbkgx6MysdjoN6pEuy/AsAFq7iRfUbOFNP47WLUsxPqPJ3ilGAmo9fB8y2YQ4Ml6VCLIVzyWsWCU5u4aHhlZ1BhgN1mSx/f3dzP6@LO/gCy647GZkuYUvuXwms7EjyyaF7IJ2kZVlh8eBIADz@Usms7Mry0OOAM1dyXIXXyrrOHaTZQtfdrf39zGdN/iSxfgAds5D@EsveNkAMBtfVldp8CfLb0N0ALfNE1qjnFbwBdPEkH0esgthsvx5kJ9MBjAccziO4UlQ1u1tWT7gL9vbGPIFFTzHs/olvmzTR5ZdeAEmlOUOODrYE8hyA5zIirLcBFdzbIAfXgaEJpBsaH/ymBMISSTLI4I2mucyDFGEPybz5MkTo@u3zA7/jF3@bELWIMQaDSv7jc8/b3Q6DXe8Xfn8GEO@@OKJ8WY8dBudhojWqMPHgTgQct4fz34gjwf1utGbG/IlhNgzIfVx3cS81Y23kCfx6WAi/foXEPIFhMyZFR5xbPDpA2gDPzt9eO4YDQoJPhRCz1GjIReRUf3xwMRZXGwz5zbIglTfaLpOEd9HpSUWV@KpcXU9UyuSP@sroJJkitcY3lbowllU71FRGVdHpUwNhq4bWXG4SZHPRtmcJaeW@o/0zVxhyXikZ9eSowLaM3facRZX9UeK/nDlnfIcFI7VtYJ89uiRKlf12qOsni@sb7xaGcpyooC/j1Y3Cu9gBBAHNR9/EtWN2qONXCTKxkbSSGcLG7gLLFG8Bor40Bs1hr5ZryvKpWmcJxKYY@zjlcQVFZeNqahWsa2MUqMSzxgbJ4qjkl7kxjhY5gauFlqDGuLdjhxjB9CNHmUKOJOuyPpmXob002klkUCphHIEnq9fBgt94SPimHLyj8YKKr8YVs@vJzQ8KlN32nW6HI@9jkJOVsmll3i6jU62B5tQafjpFaRTHPpgd0BaldXAG6nJUsFIGnE7ZozPh@kbm5JUFpr/Eb@cqyheP3@yq8FgQLyhdSltH7VVx9XwAm1/KoRbPgq8TqFf056YuLW0Gfjt8jPnWmUEIz1UeYOAp@K8kyYMQminT4pXah0n5b9zen56@l31Oor2BEZBPCN4NqdIVhjwlDva4rJazCiVwWXAeFuhXAIJEpdEjnq5XKqX@mZ/4I@hzEG8L7nF3AmiA48XJjwzRNGv8BydCKiXMtcT@OfDPtvhQHTYLohWL@0AfTNFGy1Zmvi6zEaxkVRuoaGundLO1bCAiuh10SyZruu4cgxPKD6yS0PbM9rmkeni4biDw2XWZiYeQ2t2X59VEHIXFeprtewyeyofiqGWG4lpr8grkk75TkiRK9rejQtG1zDeUF4lim/hzV1mSkvbSTxaK7aUHVZPgE/mdft1m2XZ@lqR7m1QEBOIA6IcUsRIlMpfAmKO97xQgIwIljgHnJjQMtSI1aIQIzGwroudUhWh3@PPlirLNVWtvq9J5aJUBulSHMeMkjds8BtWMw0Ymq8XR@Cnb6wVu6xRarwaFd3SAAaTrNiDaheDZL5n3cD9y0AkwPPuvfLx176X2FJzJe5XJFzve6BI1LV6aTSpoNVSNQtD6Oz6Gg6p11fhq8PQOos7MlPZzGYqq4M@AXoGxIfvBryvwRdgQN3I6jjwVnoKDJTlVGaU0fSUbuopJfPaar1OpM4V0AGJYImU71Rs4BrwQOYBlqVXeBqJZHalp7QcZmypxL8g7YpUSCPVZQMr1UU0x6bR4@AJla2uKL1lBWGWT4eDSrVWKFRGg@9gkKK@fbSe3Mgk3yUSRWWJJUqe@ZYojIKRSDBYAm4WkwnMG/armSUoNLQ/9Rpq2l/WN7KF6nC5qupQusz7zpZclmtQVddMgr/oaiToW0XwC2Qg19AmOtbEb4BKdc@EatU3s0UBIg2ERFZk5UwOjlco8fhGNh5PxIs4hbYE/kKik/iNQ3cQf6g/kkHHkwvyZhbCJ4L8Rg74QHxdl2LXEmrbDIbksSvp@up6K7od7Us2HhtJNXh9yFgnuSyxNG0T0eoxtkQuVSvTROd2abtzvF0U0Nu7UqxAOyYnm9rYmTgfz9T00qduTklulV/x5xnuzYJkJbIgV2U1MbGQXYVCtyLvUEDvSuJU5XuW0lvJMkufSbJMMoYvcOdzCZ5X9iFGrZrtXgXTEYVnODhmilHgrbhaS3x4bvWu8qsqH2ArLPaBJdMabburpz/EoBe8JloHWyy/fJ3NAfVtJ/CAobQPAhw6zVxOxik98zUbnGy@2niVf/XsxeGLw332OFPIF/Izc/pnj1MpPa7Ht9hj0Nut4wqMy94zJ6d/sL/g@1BjxVhhEF9di6/ORi3FRqW1YAeDopfLqr6VZY@AV1kB5HtbX1cz78uc8coUsJ6FkI@/9ttro608vGdBPy4ATXPJbLmsr2QTscHHb/8tnqO8qny1/ZTF0arF3/3572c3/u7P/xUtl8evi@iXXd2IASQ69fWN2NXV4OrqGj48LBerxXie1jYS4OZbOfRYOS289Q09EfNU/gbZzcW898LMjZLN5CFs95C/yetAzdhmTIrln71@z9gWDJrLrU7HypIrnb6xSLJcgNEl/LMPOCn6QV16XSovp4EBcIZ3EyMEk3gr5XJ5BVdfWLycxDPB2RwtAlWvizUgKn5wRLZi05/preAfvr/iHiueB@9BMLziBPyWyXJlncEoLp3@@Gu/lc2u/92f/@ZZ4n39ff27IGg3NzfX9WzsF5CPWw7qBcMwmsTBI3foCIdvbMFNkFpTlmJ4PWibcfhgMIfDNzymzo384Jt0gdoEkbgOdDRAd1YIbAWPG6VIi6azyYmiJIWqJmnJbqeZIhxsBc3uQtuRrqQHGAR9FCuBbJIeTFCBRx@tAzXrXm/oDkjnUyieXkuxhxAFUniA9iSW6JiUEHCqXmTplZtReZa5aRnSKljf9Dw0KQXyV3oAUZ4Cl9L9PWxg4FE7hLRsEKgaglA@KaBVhbRrkHaPR6iTr0Kl5wApxnPHI9mgRksP8NwQqdnQ9TJrCwCKLCE9AAJAGRSB2KqxLbaaYFdWMlmcWKC6xs1uaH7ACA7ySBgNsbXw9FoQuYhwFrcyMXTR8hITNdw0o54BEo6Dr82UYACA0ekNVRc6q3dvVICLzmwrVDT28OEkV6WS1UowKhHiRwNcaDVrYi7oRgKALBg9fdYqyClmJ5NY2Q@m2Q4onqTsAtep5JgAtfFEFb5eSxL835tpkSNnqooCilgAUV@8VTSBZBAZyc7rsIkmxPTsRoKFmW9C3puUKbJEEg4Jz0afaWQQqMmzeC39IhbYrZTwnu3I2EXw7exJLgZyaYg3GeExdS4MxBktfscFCqcDP4gdxoKiWD2CblsujAJonSmwaaKs6gmM1g59KB@0yS27xnD/WS6BD4qF0Gj5wkArEiKdJZqmJvNb3sCxyewEHeHFXXpkDMyTuJENnu2hfWmQASmeCm1qi@SIW@VCziejUTa3jOXxuLim1XBhSBvQJsXMjkb2VbKbTOGW3nAi0Q7RJSgSZRjGfgbSuNEz@5ClE9NkaPrAK6TTHcvvDhtk6@CZBXzV3beg27C9tLgzKX1pnVvpUzS5pzptUEfF2boY@8roWaHZIWFQgKyG9axzkw9JlanDkR7LrqdA3UsBZSdfIGwBJ1nxAGQGglMcCr4b8NjgznwqEndJGSduPlf1JaWeILWALMK4eC/ShWFH6Euf95IYSHpjLzj5TEfx4F0LRS60TH78KY7nn8JzeZI4ol2i48Mazn4PFFCnggN76AQV07wACFWXsI8BodkMThJiK4bSPqAOgNoetCw0DeK7BTxiW0KjWUoTmp4Q8Db7jK1m6bZ5fuhcnBEHHFj1pWnsEAZRsRye34KK0fhsAsgVaJ39FoTF0FIOZz@MH3A3uslMzoS92ZJAh50OpVVivFkEL7nIC7YObvQMir4EgeuQwzk5WVLkJKBNygmZow7jz0bn3C6RLCmwm5hSDDEIUgMWVBV2DI8bYhR2PS4vLzUyLTN0Lc300Daqh/e9pQcdC7RRJ@2b/YG41sLCO4nEfWsTl8ptI@P1gI9GdCvf5sMxf0pSGw@7vh1arqnE214c@8ALkJWDTp/O7eOJeo/4Zt8iW8FNhZY@PcFm2VrqKmCzArKZmo9fIxLGEM0oNU41U4As1Wiep9qXraIIuKB2B8ihsszAE62@ucFL3wtc1qAdQjg@7ZcN3hu986bTc1D1kPmM6SRpXsIAchy8iveBNYJItnnJtl3XGCsUnkBo5FNlTNoNG0PvTiHghN6EXXHjSNaoOq5NRR@F0aHvCsYezMVT@9LV7Ui5TSoMH/HwEYSPePhokmiQbHVU45oXel1jcZC50QhPAIloxgHMNTepNQkhzKAXM52jQMjxlN81fJslih3Qm79BPZYCxgCeIEt2CprQq57VbM@8XKkl0x3gaZkIATUOqKs1oullK3Qj9XsXvYHjTXnZaKMGOh@Rb/RqdgU3cF7BMoYVRIzB6WWhKZNOX@PzJrzfFwUGDKhuQSBqANu@YiWKoRFRCgTGqcoTGvOMVUVmaqRkiSDhB1oRJz0nbBRRLYII/cMiQTYhhAUtR1i@FkLgpYuXhAawKl3NQNZQ47U4UHKmqXCRUqRKiuRKVYNsAtlRKy3NFiUIh6qozgRFinkt6j@a/aVPzn4b2sX83BPD8n6hKEWbijlCy4@maC5EVVYuReoVcpBeMXqmCx1UhauholOGZFbSwWiCp4NF4BZLlUjlNxO8fugogmzLhZAVxqUSFHFc4s2St4uApJzgYTRPRBsHjCDicwECODJzo5ki2igabVQqccHBRguiXUYyOaJMjngUDj1akMmaiAaDpNAmJlZPDU2hgUIlAz6d95Zo9lNmnnGBtl3ZGzRdAoOnIM2JzCEuEDyEmjTyWbM2N/VqJNMRoTWDABnxBoIWv2ijIM0KPF0N30IZxUkZyCj@JtiAywpgMBLBRW6eSgmZjIa6oNfLSeoHoO3Kyaok67j1iP4y/CunAs/gq9/0zExD6tOemdTM3z@IZw0pG2mgESVDz6yhQMYByzZZ6wC15NJhyhzlGfzTwU2q6UbPaaT7Bm6UwCuXw/tVE8F4gOzxPR44vuE7a2sFPgiyiL9eCHAWMXLPxwBWx3ZgqBE1f2dxc312HK0SNp2ObXlmCm905Sq4Scv63DK1FNV7hdPxJEnM@vFhKaLmDISqa72OtwHV64pn9tqJQmhbEl815MN4XMLxLLgi8UEOCaSHA8XB66z9xN040TakiHZqNc@Vw4EIjEMi2wyEVRP0eQjtgqrCPGcyEiSjbagaN3yF7jPoOn2nA@odGmTE2DPoDya4MUPGYEB5STEDh6iFiAVNag5KM2UkRNQvPzkq@zKrGIkwfnYawRQxUsydpTFS1p2TXH1hcjxakN7Jp@f3JJrfk9vzS6Pq2TzzoXaJB35a0qvKBAMATrKxenc2UsL@8Y3sTGUl9EYFike4dxZbtBGphTndBtBtAa61gT9S4ZtHVllExr9aRP/bKzCIXrlv9Rl4OdrJGORNH/e7KWSZ3guW/BQAP0ig7LmZXMjae/dMC2DR/P0@6gqgr5LgstHkDzTMAQyjPTlc8hCI7@B53G90g@9pE1KJB87Jk3uRYufZxVW0V2@ZPWNsthQBmYrgDUp8DCMzklf3KzgKOhJ6Dh/UKdBJJaL2gpHoHKiwgGWM1EXEWvQNGA5ihdxDM9@Uw4PF9MPwG6IZp@xKfPYZFP54PEaGxckO/GA8GHNTiT1@c4eQo7z/4TWJBzLvJgjQQexWSE2STdwmPo@VsEj36BFCWG26yGQUKei2nP7gZh1@GonuLilUbiRSKajlKWPOi2rcuq3GI1wR8CRfz7kfS97FdPfmuQircWQTEbb7aV3IDcy4S6HZVKIYuc@tNebYN2QC@tG8m72gV6nPEahhTJJ0vkXjatIvEhIOgQ/giRNIX8ETEXZMv84ZKigbzlGJmz4YhfSNQURrET6gjQOWCBUDk/2UjQiUFLgB/Oo6TLO5MM3mjTSbU2mGLWA6yQiQ1JxKUtQCVs9tVdAz2/4C6YxBOEiGx21iGz62Y7g4LXEVt@IFK8XiF/ECCOS4GS9UFBDK8Va8sEcOL144Icd5vPAlOCZtK/4@XgiaBQK48EqOx@gvRDi@N@OFXSVxLfl4q0KQrhYvhHUKMI/4K1EESIHlBq0Rl8xsRxTTd03o2EipTDHkGC@F4ySacEnRNwP/3Hw6v@YDAnHOcoWAWZLpU51GpMfg6UC3ERjWnNOSC6I3rxzu0y6fiX16CE/CYC4ah9CDGh6LTwsjnjEMpRUKeEIGUW4W5ueI6dOXGNwjOyJ14FCq5On0iXoa6QMthcKrAFxLTNvGF/GD@ppGwSvwfvnEyIvyeSM7QXKUI1xjTczJFhL1dfyWQmFdz1z8wGs/WkM0dz0NhJcJBiC8lghtRKaDDkeLbZjYwBlMMwmF4t49KxqHZt94o0TunYlGUkG0zAXB5C1KhoIh2vgTtxUnEg@zNiWCMLCaqfFWFvYLJIsxaCLrIpoqb3yQhYjMgRZuNs9NZNs94SQ4Lm5S1Fcs6oaCuDxJklzTYhIia2hZYmj4PPVw8FpBexOfNnwNYo5wUkVBBJGYYSpcvjqfoL87XH8PFOqACDMJzFOs53elN9XrW3vZmZz3JsnerEAMTLG9xFzlKExhQnIYHUQ089t47YaKj1s4uJLPEw2xz2j7AdnCMcEddJsdW3BcqCW4F9Oe51nwPM8uJtRNjaR3oQVKi4YpCTy84GFOJ0W7Pa@84POqGENoItvofXIFu9MVHK08xEcFcGdIzls5HhbEta1J2yarpeiDIlUvMC7IafkzrOaJJ4h7WooNl2HB47B@vHf4/Ok30OlubGwkRB89nuQPWy1Oqob9OMdMO4zD/mDOsCWbQqvduHiN8@50OefSmS3fkCVcWIMygLeVBOwn2nhCyLKIPJ9puxCPw0YoKnCdT5qBMSWVUNUxsMu2BF19IIjpKyuGQBKot0DvFI3WEjgnC9yBF5/V69R91eu4GaleF70YVk2wwp34RWwpPfRcuhWR2xS@lLhJF7Z3yF4@2T5lp08qbP/F7pfsm8MX7OX281M8Gnv0YufpwS6Db@X5SYVNZhTwg/cs4IAS6LpnNs1@A0R2NpNZ42Zidp3BmMsdZTfB/U@MPnviNE1cj9ryjP7jLn/RbNMv81gVGI6OxQXfkNG@5fv8jrImoCPlpkVH0HCjPgPYBoxp@zjm7Tstq20BrIRj34FlesFJKdazoAZB3gZHHVNcScI7H2grEN33RVe14V1fAI@LNIDG8CZ3y1kej2C2NGELZ/L5ZAqeVo6fnbDt53ts9/D53sHpweHzE7Z/eAyvR98cPP8c6Hlwcnp8sPMCgwjw2eHewf7B7jZ58AxkNIaHn@nyttuyoCE4UaV5jkvcdMtp@BaddQYw0ODZpUGH8TwWH9oofSyjZ70zW/GihLfB8AOAtCbAwrvYmPkWlzKDNV/aTyC/8Og@k@UM26LUoLGUob0VRXOFbg8tS@PCQ3/M8F4bs0hnkhVyT@7LoU05Lctk8i7uOcG5b350mdpygBoSWgLciCrYgFJiZKY9Hk9tEcoypNbsOWhbi6fGNwWKF4z6ONg6UpSIYmLvCyLF/fsHNs4H6cXQA/gePLIiWd/lAGw19OAAbI17oCp6gHtBWE5ADP3DIYpnts493vQH@7T@yzZCjx2DRrF5kSdeb1SlBpvcnmz1Bz0ytM9neej@HMNrWhZF8QgeDdX3esEldg0TWB5korhyCPeqAaQMwqaNSw1iG5s9pIYNocANuO/HaPseU0oJjZ3iZh/TtvgNBp2eYfMtTZOtOMR7LI@GKUpit7UVXg3Q4leXEwPidR3T@Qjj7Qmt0LxvPIi5cyNFQ@x5pOtlgi1ld2Vg50YGfhk0gEidGuk0qaeiM5mIxmkLVlY8BzgS520/ROGBnVvDpjkVIbhi8I317l1CEDk1NU4K9h1S7qCK8DbGFF@zbDsutHESq308X4JSsNl1Br7F61CZLsHkgiiAxo4NUntdKk@lRpdCzqRoO3Yk0QZw8YJUG8CU90mVOJ4vkofiK2jr4Q1VtI8Os2M0nAszsnaWwkWkSxOnX0AR5rfrYW9Dt6UK/VOayI4PdONhvlTe2zlTP7xOoX19Lhb4nVLBJkJ@Q2If04LmQet8tAHRRb1LtLTgkgZv2MDYYk@dkJbYygNkMA7sWjCue1wvhmF8@/BNfzw8MutPnu/fl3gsFSUTl8hDr6tMpFuKVYMkUxSnxsRej4jshMyCrFcCnxThDOX1YzwngrVQBIrYKEfobtPpyxGECAlK1xi2QbKI649EdYf4E6xMWycCRZI@SrQ@0q@UnVKynEhPdo6wCDmVQESnAsx4O9Jk/wn1VzfQ7d2ODuT3/dHlb80d7x4@Cdverdg@KW9qcjEu3i1FcN0f7Ydb0PLO7ZdCC2VPLUbMO8mb2EJOD5kztRwLd8fenuLrG3VHbQ/QYN@LMygh0khqQ5uWqAMDmAqPkIiimShEJ6d7leNjJvPxCcQFuYdDhpYQg4h7id8dwXfPWjYJOy1UmsLBcqg8BT5TW9fCIx@3NOa5xFsgKoQOkhL0CIXF9E2NJPVEz0IqBO2mJ4EYUG46d1eBDPKqAvE1WjwF4RWbqGFhAaW5xYzxzsfyopu6Bd1SXDeO7smnHdO878Y7l9xxFFF084/RwZMi8@vvJdePC0E6XMEy3w6pwC3QpPHaUY2dQMIDANS06Rq8pVqCKsVN81zBjgW0wx1emWkN@@/PUMRIXAnnunBErAvlWGSN68fLgZpDOw@xGzBwS6cI5DuUISAQ8eSzFa3QxKTTU6a7IFAy8Tagx1GugOi162J4gagy6SdLoUIebWvLlJtqkMsazs4K3MXFQJ/h3ub1WfEwmxRI21uTUn81SfFeYiqlgOZzCxMEAub1XG71LtyzpQiiq39f3LwPmZWffn8A4/sJSm/s0fQ@cO7B81QQPmGAW0jHt8oHDWYmIqg6c/qUqbJTZxTNH@SFzwtBZtCwbLOLdx9Np5pgo5m8zcfOe6QodgK5UYZIEw4LylvNDepf354cCuQ701v69PR4Y0Mg3CN4/YvwcF3EOErEC4@JTvuZrmsTGD@W1Hfw@BidRrr1zBwdmuMbWnlhMJCW2aIFaItDRnxbbSqYYqBEaFZRw7vScFKvODurp@rFaAn3D55W2ApZPGtPTUHKrpyIiJwly74tAyR6aToCew06iveZV4Av5CEVoAQy0aE8hWiTuDNvRBFQlqtkrF9s@xQiVZ@t9LbXNGy01JGS6ZrhhxCRJl8rh/uJeRPqmeJUfMicN7AViJWSVU2mqOCH87iIaRoFr030j/RTEhqrFxskb7lZ1Ujr@cz6pkSls1N@ql/drKVWmiWZQZ9r2H1v6F62zjtO96LNemzwpjFqjt@9ZSy3xvCIb/Yht@2or5fwdKvC0AxInm1miGFFBh@RncozmTGNDPThejKbDL@LS2h2ED40Vi7gCYgZLmUr/YAL8aScX@pX12slu5Qp9qt2rYhn9fxkyU/qSQU9HkLnCaKFL8hX/Rp2pb@Izraa9gVzh40xjJLCsx@Mzn5g/44zXGLPNs2X0zZj6QFuVsMzJJptXirhrdHImRLqP9IDOsSj42lvmi7G2ZaWBTkA6qdAWfVG9DtOSA8y2nDgOxQiElKRhdh76730IDh1lKEJAwCpWrUgO1uEZwKj4LoP9x3z3dCqzrUxHY86JiIoqhiTpJ18Jst4BBAzKo5eVWuSp5lGs4uZwPsB31M0trXFLw6/hmCapMOdGoZLBx8yNXTi@gY8BrSYgEmQYu7R8Q0Jio/vOjq4D01B@XTehTa6S6QIYghu42ZXdByJ4m8BATjhH3CVShMzmEKxAj2RH/WjuQM0Djc9rsdVBDwFySvlARYWcfP0ShPktOObaITJCjKB/4NLJCenFXxECVSd3m4UI4RPcHAiCS1DizcPaUlVSkFlfPQm0ZRINDWIFgBHSPHgTmrgRBaMfp6Z0HzGbNfs9SDTnBYPJuRAJx3HFeknw/S9KqZZCzPPw9Ub4epUuMbDeaYmUBr03xOgQhRIjl1N4K6ZPAFL3UirxEg30aCmmxpoHBPY4m2wnuY7dWsCXA6rknNlGLA1FaBGQl7NqX0esjQVJ2TwMLzKwwV/Z0XNh7mcgn08nT4@JVFBJu2NFVtJZrhUs63eI945hSHIZjLDm@h5dKxvYjveKMWRSSFOQEHDaXxqtuXSBEtSDyQOtRm5vPVY1oQy8UiZzQY/dHijYc1pIxEqUZpJItyIzhdCOhS8FEFBOJHRWNByy0HksYg8jqBFqKUgWX5o8UYDh6LNNvESHmN8jz9BY5/OXAAXmx/4gOd8xAvPDyNPE4iE7pI8n0zT0gSPfXBPUahbepFJ2uNZjPOFxPPIJG@YpsmPTLdxlnsplBNRQRFIiht0D0MEpScAesC@i6oQA6@lX6RXpM8NUKEHPXPEtnEUYdBpKmnqPDoaR/XQoBHap4Th@WDQw0VFUuwu6cSzsM2RzeFqygRjZBlNkw5w4w6HT6FLnB@HSBo7RMyXuP9jEuANOx1@7TxDO0YgWnFCxfI1adse8/kKaDOrWX4q3GRDjy@KwmC@E80ErzneepDSdGe7JoEu5oGWI/Gitnn7FtPleCwETWpBl1aQpO8Mreb57ue4XLuhZ1b1CMkuxGpvRltdmxyUAiIFAdkMqKs5fU2SIku/Tb70qyLCFHuKHf1XwJvmBd6NK21Dj0GAHiinnulemC1Nko7NcI0X8SIr48IjHpt2hm6Tz92AboV36uJpXy/FV7uAw/CJ/TNfDW7SUlhKwjWpyWIyVPWF1UICBgdK2g4u/tJ6BJ7q5/TASH3TB6KsJNh0lmhpWeSFdJc@zjMBNdAsSWTpISSD7fhWE2qGJqqkHqDiqxyTxPgN4JGcQHrNnoGHfLV5GcDTLxMKBBkIVopuy4Mk1sQ/KQ9MFCxYQjeCmkmD9HOorUBzN10LpO@EwFQrFC2Sd6jg0ycHJ@zkcP/05fZxhYH76Pjwq4O9yh7b@YaWsHEdnAy4sieHT0G6hIvlfFH8EDzk7ROIKVOAtP38G1b5@ui4cnLCDo/ZwbOjpweADdAfbz8/PaicpNjB892nL/ZocR0wsOeHp@zpwbODUwA7PUxRqkE0aRKPHe6zZ5Xj3Sfwur1z8PTg9BtKcf/g9Dkmhov22@xo@/j0YPfF0@1jdvTi@OjwpMKwYNLewcnu0@2DZ5U9DdKHNFnlq8rzU3byZPvp05mCHr58XjlmtAcgUsqdCuRyeweGqpgSlXPv4Liye4oFmrh2gXiQwacpdnJU2T1AR@XrChRn@/iblEB6UvnOCwCCQLa3/Wz7cyicpNxBFaiX3RfHlWeYaaDEyYudk9OD0xenFfb54eEe0fqkcvzVwW7lpMikp4cnRLAXJ5UUw2uJKGnAAdSCcHDvvDg5ILodPD@FPuPFEW5nSEAlvwTCQC63IeoeERh3OWBpgUiHx98gVqQDVUCKvXxSAf9jpClRaxupgBsmdk@jYJAgEPE0Wkz2vPL504PPK893Kxh8iGheHpxUElBhBycIcID7Lb4B1oFEX1CpsZ4gX9wJzCoFnJui6mQH@2x776sDzLmABg44ORDcQmTbfSJoDm05LUUmSywH5waMfnQCpX3T68JEA4w3Z17mz8WEBo52D/cqoPFx@1nyxB8tDOdnDB9Fw6CjCQPhdcrATMtsDDt1y27/f@0923bbRpLP5le0QVsEJN51NwXFkh1PnI0ns7Enl5UUCiRBCglFYgjQIu1oz9l92B/YD9hP2Yf9lPmQ3bp1owFRlnLZJDNnck4sEOhLdXV1dVV1VfUUQ0VNNbZvXCajKt7X4IF2rk5LH7iyQ8woVKFc7na/POqCnvu62/Wq96mZA@OuGmLk/lApT8aI2dlR8Ub7zpMnjPaDHKIO1@QYk9zw8HgBSzLy19ixLbgMPdVoDEKphjH42LC2ECV8KHKBByXAGSmUEW8wyLokAwT9joQaqKKrm6/3u2gFRb9HKjRN4J/JD9kP3husF8Cc2arVaKAOS2BE70LdDXdCmQ3oH0ksEA2py3oSht@P3KbdHar89dF0OnA9T9ehsimogSPXu6N6LxwVqteK9QlYOlSW7O@JVrtJgjGny4IyJfNSn9HIXPynm9IfT0PDqRvQJkpdkSlabJPuGldHf6OqkgwVGDxBk4wi36ujr19@hcpcs73VKbz/xLzntYXegJg/Fva7E6p3Rn8@OeMCsMAopQagJJJEF42GVUd7k5jCV1DwAgtRenzaqi9C2tYBJSDHzoOx3SduxrNoYUMPbPgPXxy9Ov7zixfAORHarb3t3Z1OySTJ@rrKf7/BfiivKeUIi2EbBzGNPlmr5BnIPbRSrEzYGfkTATcaWBBzjetJo5eYrsF4ZeT9lJCP4XATvM5jgg54Toh4cBTl0XhY0vS6cmUKAbi5oXo4mstgQRJ@AKIS0YC4qoyXNGsL/AfbNstfL3EzICEgITHKJguUC8oF8T3nhXYEJd2G0uxgkbqj6ZiTrhkckKWLvGMxdpZ@CW1bs5iwoyKuV5p2qglAPCxCobTXxIRX9p8oXYjYeSnXF7z5WugNHr@RdHSUnC5I0qP0NaDxhamJ5ujM5iyDPpGWzw59mKK1NdPTgUJjvidA0doTq7HJ72GtBgLlDF0GfVVouGPSgRS7JP/WpxVPvWdKxRwc2E5HKFZ@A@WuGo600tFpQOS3Ti6huC2Tq4SxdmX6KOki35h0FBqdOTT9LHxQ@78hTla0fwAKJ7SeYctK2XcvTFKrjCvQXgkp0ZU@T7AOMTJs2q@@yZq5tifmwgxMDmkWHD0DKJDZWeoX31CSwqG7AgFI5GjXsNevcTi7CEBzeup4Uh2PQyb9y9hVslforeJGu2dVkrmq@gAFf3jKY0OT1d1nUFE9ZR@5VBQu4GK9pXqcONzGRsvTuTsa62T0MKucSPOCHVGL5NSUpaUXv6RJsnaZgcl2BKLo9a0ncuvKymKZY/hyquV17OyW9oAFbdDnIQK6ctzogc@uuPlsiZz7/A1lsMN02Kgz41Yk6eZ65HQ5DrGdxwOyjOA9o@kVbhdjbp3S7GWtKfcxOYVgJ5mHYZYjEJmvVwes0yZ7ZaAnMyXSq4H@zxPOKB@yiUuXqHMyD4HQDo2vq1fBEmEe32/cTtb5BqL1MN//ywmlHuynvFPG04Q0d@gFNf3HSYYR7YYD@1CGJfG/dDSNRle1aAF/qK@ajFwncQSdgRJMrhL6r29VCCi/ZP6EVDmnE2NEesIbmf9Yiy/4xGvXPH2DT2Jn9mFQABy8weNUEYMQZJSb8Ajv5moj@DA33FdROBvYZjnYTQdBjBYgEr@nE9p2tfVKMsj1gzQJlyCF9hvRokFtdN1PpxeT7rPpOBhF0ygAXQFTaC94AeLjkh4x/@doNr1K6MoV@jCwCg2W2TNnMOGMXvjbHI11rCxPSRrGrn0ins6WRxeciICMt@hmpgzPpCSqcTHdlqmztZ1VKuUjHMnjq@V1bq272VpVmQ@PsQFZVoeFw3qOUkwp9MUKb@zcKND7UAELxp6qqcC7xScsB/E@oIhOAnIQa2BunIDbg0Dt4FaITwaL6oDS2c0wlU/4PMRLSxKXXlcDvB4SOP1HeCj9RLX2mlZVNuQvMKUdPixvR3d79zeGHgD4GeC3NldRyypCoIS@Q53PJ2GZWfJSAizkgIZulVXUBEBJns6iESi241yj3UWx1fzn5W3YICcT2JolY9sNqsQV6YLwjbd0uV1gOd2lp374QVVUxaPMELgjHqVu83aCDe/y0KTFj@eIbLxBxvRMWnYtoG9DVR@whHcDFhw4bZA5C@/dK6bdvu@sFRDor3Jqsm4IcB29X1KMg8g8eLIynQEzdgrYE2@DSpJO48o9sXcr71iZ5GsVrvued6erKRObv9horw8Itf4SH5edUhGeAtHkMUZOTUBDqELRsyHzIhIXfhfXm99d3oGH23CWueiYTcXM94DXPm6Kb9FnVG80ZkkR7JjvsmPen3Rh4N3bOYi0ySJ@lzhGF1lGd8mPVlMFNBks3R9DRH0CewEfA8Ac9jsA3NnzcytSi/5YOnum/pTLl4j4xFTfGBYIfCke4vk/JiLjIxLDpDirefgEE7vSaVKr1sN8tfiBG8RglbCW2ULYiphNVoGOKJ/80O2iw0oLORE8HdqH7CZNvEEY5XEXA4McuneXtdZZh1tamJZAlqVSH2pJRzTDz5Puglq5gQpY4itQYUZ0gzdd3H9UP3csUA5a4Nr0WXxJm1UcjKc2ABr4x/7UXaAMnHUlNXMrKr8QusQaYC2AGjIah6w9ofQXzZji8YBdlhGI9vzaxT8bUgMTQO80DbaxymKwxCKeoJtXm6dqh1wlIyj@jeiXpciiLqlL0EDIEEN9vwUtYIZMgh4N05Tcxaa8HKAyR1DRb@GyhJeUYDNzKVzxHZEqBba2rRLNVSX27TZqKxsBwWJ1mQwQkFlWF8lagY1uJSxWid3V48lKgECsaZ8xDlMhs5LHoZk5RiA8ErSGo5y0VLUpFEwft7a93EdD3/R1v2l9bRa/An4MhCe1VvHrXjP3Nddtu52vmqsJ@PDsXnMfARWeDbDhCj/vPwp@sLNnG7dES8nISRniCjxBVeoK9bb6d4k6oLBfLWPo9uzYY61@dflSjlx@7w/n8laSKb7z8werfSM1IJJcnhKf6WgKl/VBElgd3OlxVKjo6lRuJgJeq7TTofryzYsXubyivaV2dbkMZ9vNZhNpuGenUddevGi/iKaNfOnGcD4eN@KrT2df9hrE@vHa7XEyfaIV6BBmBNZEUp/ORnyVAMIARbF0TSIlUdWfD4d2zn48JMO5g1njkhJur2j/iYzbxZdvyMBDTcr@eo4DxPGdK7P4rgKWM6UVfRICtdEp9a2jD3AAPfhiiJ7A5rCEGkO@rP1pYNvy/MP3uIHgVRg0WZQI13ufOcg6n4Tj8bSqvprOxgMMRX9wXazw4oVdoclF8JCLwkfnCSU8rarwbTS2AlexiE3q2Jzel/TFBDrDOGZZ/yIcfbyIXefkWwd2FRjyBg5zAzMdV5UzcjxJO36PZpkOAex7lb4MYrdPeCoWhp1eFnD2BBBttqorVZ9cEY@uGBGc3V0akboa3DplA4CheyQK6KzoNL00kluKG@Q6p4vWEHHY5DYEJkzqcb8aGMv023HFt@lweD@mSAnleWJ/dYZIFmlagbL8AJ@Yj/mfarCsXxQyVrB8g9c@3OQ7WKGLFUqlx33/L1fu0dGRehRvbKijo2N4qNXU0fGReo4vjo/Vc/h9jL/X/Pb2dod57nPvPbw81i@v1TG0QQbOjf7F7Dn8hG8@BiahvzBO8aOG/6jaedT1Dw47SePk6BjjxuHpr//2H3/99/9sHMmP/8Ifx/Tj5FtTqF6vNx713z9au@7g75PnZ5VHvZNH8Vll1EEqQ3b/51kSjAPLgbHeL90RpDMYR73bAneMB0eUkLcgeuy58I/vgwb2ww/8dJpmj7PsEdNyZtWDcXwRUHVFLRz6laPK2ho8HfiVf6mQ7UTeB@b9O3ivPOTlFLdPqMWrZ9TR62cvX9qZr5Hrk/Q@DDFNC96NKMcm0SSJYFDnZX3nXO1E1evqrKbODXjoatDlgnkQWc1kYP5VgNSjI78QOj8VtQEPRsn0zRZ5Pie5TEYk32nTOd@/FYim8njwhA91qI0NYHhYvsPu0hJ6icMHcPEUxq@dtHa2z2rlcrlk7uTq9onNUW8x9WXuaNLHuHQGw5FAMSwZGDtfdI@4gAYRGeUy3di01uebxdwJqtakMbHCXa5Y8jzam2ggJcPm2MLN8fwoY6HCR7dgqWROgQAoGyzve6QEAFCE1wExLsUX6yZx2I@GS3PsjpciZL3DXolRW@tqeCNoSzmzniPjejjMGgSEoBRA6WKw0WKDjLwplI2I2/EY9W8QN24S1bnkn1ZbNMHGKSWejpejMXTmkjtPcgXcCTDvyWSNJzqaC3vgmr1wiJe684rmCcvcSRHuXoimiEkfFMwBXlE0xrRQLPDxESQlRIT1gBKOXFE2xGgEdzxhJ5bpEB5hw8dALr6OjchwA7dUIShUalE51lecCR9Yjz1PxVwSsQq/swNgIg8yQZI@LHet5Y4CY09q4tsDobQYb5dDRVrSU3qykhxaK@YAFqTKSzwgw8MxQAqWrNN1VsAalup8PDk34@cjtQRvxKPzM75wjrpp8xk5cCzTjY7Ypu7YHd1h4ypdfjUJUkFvPE2SqAfISpd6migLH/uvz6DV00qJOxNqwYM6RDC@Wo/NirLHp0kpXMQUIs7wPkDT7kRTQa4gHivimRifDZdzJ8WT6aRGLLcXplGfnfi494eaF8d4TEve@wTY7R2B8sAHlXqCqYdTneBGzihpqrN2CE/oL4/r/8KI3gHhTMy8wqIldgEAMsRhZuc0Q1LWoqEEaiCPFIGRXJAFgw9yhDkOR1Gaq1OVJADs@cyjuNaox0V@jgDb2C1gFn31aVX2rH3mXPCt3QOQ8epvwGj3PIm/XUV7ejC4q/Hdh6YmD4lCuvZu0ofhRxocG2pYwYA@XL7V/AzR5op7HeUxw2ySgzypqmwWPtgDNS4gMr9YpxgTakC4RREntRPARruADWCnhWWQceFmrnmLgJG47Z2ceFQBvTxdLBLcYN6aXjSkSATXJRNV8v7/u9/cVPZmGCILiw9KIR3AHp25OZhUDsUmV67Aq1AL6pKfDVjjbI5J0dh9QnYUzKIS8SK1OjVwFLrSQ5cZrpGkFFOKDvh5UrHnslBVjzerfZavXatwVNF7HVvkWpJO7EnIkXx9wJt5a2dbt8tBQ3T0Rr@udXSTBAcZnwk9O4Jy2l6DIaIHvTDomh8zOderSEPr8JrL6zGLZAHCZa5xaouOaKSc7YmyAknsq3A0T6cv019epqf0xnLWZ17SjZ8gFwQgBouIEHgNeYJH9ID1fim1APlABIyAfaiCJITnUoklD9EwnVfJ6Hi6cJvVU@fUqbZ29j2H9GQjh5X7CWhG5X7ICbvw1kDRPSkxINm134bMwme9aDAIJzodKFSV3synrjR7gub894bdJXzJqkNMPHQsXp7UYBLpheCanuNZMLoM6PGP0zezYPkSNiH6@fmE5/M1tvcFbEZ4LRB9@YLX6NEARA3nGvXkjCbuNUQKWQpA8umnJBpwMjhLXFiBgPAGArhPM/4kP1gLDfb42XZhpGfaN2FSz1lCSdiR95wPTs5LfOfsJV6K2uV3QJuudSmtPNKnwk3JIiPgB@1jZr3lGizqj/GkJ5zkziF09lohPL65mGtV1RgItKlVrg8PZco@uecG@uRcFJu0f9G9nI/TSEZ2Y1h6XFipeP0uqZP6xuRbruAlk2ERd9Y4sN2TCFZppssQo8qwIEqYbsXSHzW6afxkdsyEBlFVOPNEe4voo3nd@cDcsHR/qFUNTAxhHdho5RTHWbLUDajdKWX7rDKjfphTPhAOQAqCsR7T3cfEmq/tOcYZxtQVxEzM5P4aOvvfspLLb@i0IcOS1ksx@hVEBuZhma5Pnu1V1ZRDbEurBUrhy6@nl6FotqJOWMqrdXEZ53P8zRXWOzS3nPRnoUp7Dtuyy8PcQssJh9pl00KnEWJoZ7ZngcZqCyO2JEEsJ5bYfMaztHTNgdEr2QYrJVCSYS4K2VpiMiNdwd6giRubZ9WIETc@eVp6MxIQFQWaGmimKrtbtrHJpddo1ct2MA1rXqa0RXaVbaCZzLpCCTdkcCeiwpuIav00RDFcq/DEX34xNOURkMfSdam0inwN6xDXLHutmyiWG3yJEPfQCMKFNlYIur0x5q3LACs2h5fGi2S/r4XhdXU0AraYl4XZwzrI3rHWwwpkUohaNoY49oqfzzCvaxmkqxL8jzl2gUtdokEnZwEBkbVRMoUoRgmxQfg21giJmleNslcSn6FGmW@qae22POrkHj1hEOjPEO@ZDeJRzPBGABZuKCRyrKuuBLHdvfvRXneLWTo3vpUmaeDImVGa2fN6HKMz@V1W6kZZsim4CppXnvqJBmqylbR5D0I7T6NcegAgsKSBad2gM6q9IQbeJIRhmKSQbM7N3LBYP9SG7t@T/VvjWPsqCAUYAaGppQOUz@gWYp5gkRAomJIWaOVxUgFUm1COlb1kohqJi4TaHCXrHbwlW/VKg5CZFdqlE5Vd4jlLLaviSqupthCp8spqysUsl2jNoKOjsI@GcGOlSjzLHixmhwa0LZdCA1gcrGeazLErezhra0pgI5N1QcZYqejnEMVw5JBxOmHmXCRdYEL4khAvWwosEyP1xSvtD1xASmSrc221IILsNZNDMgtNI8P7fGIwvxo7VPVD@KFgiGkhyIVwQhzVpB/JoCn9WIQW8XkHkZJB72@HSn/UTNyXVOXq6Ntokffi3Rbvxfbes0waaG3A3Qf/Rn2ONaXgxmz/Uet2APAD3n/JTAH/MIFSvEJqAtmB2yepJ9ddP8j0unqSdvnmbsN@UY8Tl7vBALZjYLYU2VQFPTElHyRl4Vk72FKQ@4/aMLWSzt0LKwQVE0EpamZSO9PLFClmlvqrI@MJU0MJJX4AzZF7EUUT4tHVtM@x6bBB4fchRaaTXttitQgVIq54gj8lxO/BkDPlDWUl8wjUele6lTEIPDQIlrGOZ0F6LxErO5Jjh31zeX2RDpN6Sb388SLZfeSy9XvLZeV1smmvZ@LZejkG2WLzJ7bx68ppmYEW2nEM5A4uVDLgk8oBKIYJGqOHcWbMF65lH7n9dLHvH@LL73VjWP/diy/rBv39vBCzngkx/ZVCTFZAavXR8Eb1THliD7BsJ6Qhr4vYw/1N8/3ButH9TVf2x5eBq6ycVJ5St/h6Rbfp1VRqGEKVDsn@uLIj5LW8ps8dWdvnyr25oHm@s2148x/b8N/3NtwwuMCEl3fsNNbU/2Pu/x7mHlMojveae83uL3bua945NmE5hfNWpZyHqnX40e7p4nnzdLG/9flfymn5sN34agZ/0/Jfyjt7ZX6EB/i1qX@9LR@WD7DYznV52fB9Hx6llaMX0Mrhp6ZNLLU8gH8Ot3W7O8vyYc2n6j@UD3fgodVuAySni4/3Txd7Tfzf6fyexA/7dMUIH7e1GlNeFdkQ@CxQXORJLZ8mWZPPrN3hJZKAVsfzBlLc@aHRGgGMzjOL9l5TZBUgIM7/8DaUK6AuQ7y6y5inKIdJSnk0OOJC538QXz2uBCvAdOHBH@qCdnsRvbKcEzrdBEoJGdDq/HF9B4@uzyUNhQHAJJ4gMZNduUG9cKljTLGFfw@bHzkmMcUTR/JWOLbHv5xtyq64J7vi/5ZVvEwvppP2isTqZfUMpisN1XcJw5JMojgOU5b4R@EkhC0ZjenRFAUdvOmtj/fijaPv2f3viW5c9amh7ndJl2NzuKF6vFTOo6ewsqJL0orewarUz3g@trOlfwHjxjvDME5GR9eMovRi3qOc@G9my5fp55SJooF5tVPOStEAWa7XuAzQcYAyySdAYlAC2MFsPmnQ3WIgsGGsDKZ/vwy@B9DwPlMY2qALxdDY/71Ll4cmYUwhLovh0KGbesLx4HUYB7OAs6ah1/w8GIUvMTEMTEZy4aDyVFZ/pOCa1M6Oa5QlwjjI4XIlU40zWBHvTyo6/JNQqxSGG9ONMQ7GqQsTIt7t1ClqAmo5HFpAt1QPp9M0K89R46YC/czXoJxgMEkcGoKHg9mIgJvj@Dc0EBtKyQuCI/spnWYvqCOCZqYivMkBRxVO5pdEO@Zm1ZPWkzPJm@a3rBuuyeN174ncau44iFCcJjE2t/bwy5x9L@lcsiSpA8w4QLBmSKAgT8icTgsvQVNIkmnvO8r7g1wJFiTSX11/k2VPbvTwiMbuSTgKiFdc9aKUCgyihApgzcboHcjujKJqjlR781FS57VAgRVRkszD7d29LQKIdnxddDDt54q2G9DyLJgtGwTcRXo5NqPYTy/UOHwbjsV7hcCmjLK8KInO8FKtYD4mt5Ydj0gHUJkbKWDB3a/yu@cfv/js6M3Hz6sgpmxj8YTCkkxZ10Iuf96g78MxZmpgMsIqvHzrvZ0tJnI3qVaeokWOQX9qo33DBlg3kCR13AOi2K34VE38LLhhFaPaPhlVzXH41XT2vUlcjMsNQZnTbQeORq5e@eUyhnQl2FcZSTCX2ADq4MB05PZsDIznRqFbeQVgQLhbNwWKHCP/RMp1Dh7WamZNPaGnGjDWWu2QjSzOs3EEimfli/kkx20rtHYCVQEmh8f/zNoeVogv1J2OuvBRj@/0/WbHxO29defee3Mr8hChcBlxb6bHSz1/7lwi0xxAiEdezjpk8n/@u@J1rrMkOmM39TD7v3rn6@TFdWbqH/N1qW4l6cNkpVDtXT0NF@kzzjbppx1ToTcdLOXa@2egVQ/cd3Yfseu9h716Y6Pv@5vee@hyFmMWyhiYYfgGWvQ6@G6Ye2dCxBqnpxO8A3kdQ/e@fvXZJzDl6CcWJunJt2frjxrVSsXzOjiEwKf4vuefv/oTWvlnXp2s/S9m00vByywwndRhti@Tk@YZQV91cGgNXIXAOUdhKqNPjpdvgtEfQVpyKwGgAN2SKDAOJiU6CCS@rIO@SShz4f0gNo58Jz@5jvd@5FOpi1k47LCt4jrx37ojr5PCnwu7i23owm@3qfUUKvno1VTAejSB3fqTN68@8ysHgcJW/RWrorLRM8QBhEIE4@KrI7wRKUc6wFWIqlKO1iOCgf82Ks5hfiwHjeCw0rm@vhWezzinKwg/lYyAB@68KhQ3829OaWeWUcEyDn18wVvbHz5@41ShLqZgwZcT3N6WxLQ4iNXXfTC5IaegLXD5Gsv4/tbaGr3DKvPE99vNpocZUa6htQSvMIdmeWHNOtezwB@4BpFBHK24sKddbzc4kCVptHbaze3dj6Yz2CJ8vBN9LQEW4qPW8jZKl2sgG4a@vvxnDeRk2E39h1vre59Hx//89f7rneduv/dpy6k63yXktj@LbQBmwVWdxSLgsTPJ90pAYORiP2jEwffTxtag2QfJs7U7CHe3w73m5l5/O9zc7@3v7/eHW3u9wf5usLvd7zUw3zhVqV9GE5CSHCZ/7HZ4v25vE8z22s394bDV2tkdbO8P99vNzc2t3t72oLm1NdxrBZubO4P2Xm@/92GpLYOnBAxW813cO4oc@PHtwl3pBm@X2t7/AQ)

Versert is a 2D language with `\/` reflectors, without string mode. It takes the path of SNUSPs, deflects from first `\` on line 1.

Versert code is on line 6: `@!:!8:6:2`.

`!` is used to skip unwanted instructions in SNUSPs. Only one `:` needs to be skipped because there are two `;` on line 1.

`;` is input in Versert, so `< nul` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

## 269. [Kipple](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Kipple) ([cipple](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/kipple/impl/cipple-0.2.1.c)), 12500 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x
#  
#
#  
#
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 #ata",_"[];=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers951 6 4>8370::$/  \0Vngt=BFloatk:pext se>ExPrs min94 Cr~-<u Uint 22FACw;re-  2:t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEAQIdPMDvM172U0Oye6@94JodAEoANUEqtCoAgk0mx0z441ZjaXwyuNZxWi01h3JlldaO8Kyw17JYSkcIb06FH7SD2j5ZUOxofkHs@eczCoUQIBkj0YRCxKorMyTJzNPnjx58utk3XA7v/hFBD/syOmO213HY57peqw5sC7Mgca2x@yxYbmZ9KokIdTWoD3smbbn5qUI0xmzzUu2bzesJvgxzzk3beudOYCwNGP9gdMeGD3mdQwPXiyIxXbN7vvee481nF7PsJsuQK4ydmRAYGvYOGdG3fUGRsOzHBuC1hh7bneNXr1pMIAwB/2B6RH6DAMUjXOKMx2SZeypM3BNTL5huq6DnuuMbZq9vjcuwUsOIIyB5RxsPft8JvIGY58bkLN@1xzN5EVPsZeWOWjOxNB19uJ0b2/WN82@VB2b7d3Mn77Kng9co2vM4l9jW0PP2fdm/TNsq23aBktrG1p6NjDLtgfGjSjrbGAazZbVNTXLbjCVdcxu3xww9GEtZwBV5pndXCqXqm1NYmoNjJubBM6gLfofZgzaLgQ6FyY4TaiJvmU2WWvg9Jhhu5eQkr6RmsAj2o1pdmhABoHR2BsXYjdN5tpWv296PBCKaw4oGFJmXcs@lzj3HQ2c5rBh2W2AM4Gu/aFHZXKlBkQrsb7gYQ0dLEJU4GCQhROnZ4brwgXmhVy7fbNhtawGJ4458kzbhfK6GrOg7i6tbpc1zS5EmGBvJJjrsKEb8qp3jY7W0CQkLqbCeuddZrFGv894EBQDsrSXyjGz57yx2DsI73ZcNur3mGv1INhrOK2WabJ3Zr8D0VmvKTUdicGn0Z8pWfC2bAKMbULpdo6@Brp5SE67BVlrsnoIDvJBeaYSG7YD5Bsw2@hxbmj0x1R6QBPEaDmOhv5Nx3TtqMcuncE5q5sNA4uNiblmu2UMu5Ci1cLqAD6wXNZz4AmVaDPIFkT2kBaIGxOT5hYEk/Gr1@xDw8TqdZBdoK79Wr4cGMAfA1fUo2f1gDssL@oy03AtlFgQxTXtJnFGP5BlDpQ2XOnswoKGB6QYDgi3aw6I9Qkvw1IASiPgVeVyYHnAEViKLXZkGgN2OjDNGOdT020YfeTScJKQmIMpeFgQjRhzczNaPtyLAoPyGJrRB4YcrJ5@5wvJYFqRLdcK8C3KckEqP9tlV8tn6OYyE5i4P1CMGCt@YG7y7MyE70ivJ9uDawmwSkCVLks6fS9pqH3IoOpBBpMGOtGlXqS1fjeUMNucqYNQs@FQTagNEALsRYJK1hgOBijdJ0Q1zqHQXcduAz2hsIOhzas8m4IqAP5ruglmXpjIA7yOnEui8GkHOAT@ATQkWXiHQwSFLgeaoqCon67rdIcEBzFdD9sjUAWiIsb9FnvBWobVxSgQjqh4rgemC8yJcYZ2E2u@Z9lmU2N@NkjqDKAtXkByBiAlD2gNvZBsoUwBMFSEQ0XFoI@/@TvNdhvwbDUazqAp2PUFMHuDukaDMgudG0OGdWyjS9kCuASmzqNDAhdG12qSlDPssUiCMkGpXjrDbpNRQ720oMl1DBC2JgiIhmdyJneGHuQxwXrGOZeIFudcKHjPqEPFUgKUNhVbZY93oJYa0MyJZ9Te0GvlmNovs6ibfKU8yiuPls5MyFxMi60sJ5PtAjCctkJe8Ba9jXNebE11Fa5nuI7VlPpjr@PYaaY2mNwoOn3TVqJTOKKJ6KAejWkoqZVYwSo2tJZlN5XoJvBiCRKOxgqNYqNi5auFmejhJAHNJaLB5moqjZiMooYaxUWyB8qFBpLshSpcoTDHrSHJMVgLeSNhZv0uuEeEVBfkSwcZBOSQ5nZNs6@kND2GYgLh5pYbA@aVdAaHKHDeqsajkWg8XHTCACWdKig21lPLQbHV7XdQ3wCi2G4fZO4AebdhAPe42Kl5oNIlWJ34mnpCkCwkEy/NKEjtOghSn4@oSfImh/FVFJQCw6QJTbdksxlqyCAEoC177g1p3HVQO6A8Yc8DosPGRI02VA1E5gXZ4gXhKZHPdJHObRAoiK1uspxat6ARYHMDmS54PlQ2AF9NcxjAxhtJSPb0jDH2alw1mDQY7NMM1gPxMBizhokyB4SPyTsUTGRI7c8FvZc5LZZS05nMdBu70cS8QXJL/QaE9LvkrS0JCx9uTChoWAvU7K5ht4dGG@SFY0MUo9Ew@54QVFAS1wNRNNvfkKcqOk/N7UjLj2fTpk7EV48maaCQ57UnukIDpYtQ21XQyVD142MB1rQGIJagJ59JHQAuZhKXXyPIVAZeywuy4GsAwGTmyGwMPZBqwMCXHavRAZ7F3NlcLvJOaDZ58AqnDpJdbQVJY2b00sO0pCUDL8zGQhQq1uhNPNC5IqrSlAdVftjjdsyG25uD2AmyCB1ByFdLGhrw3h04e47tzEEKhAzQIsh0CK8H0MROUCmGjstXu6ixBppyUEVQZyA1oOUD/3U8r@/moZ@wvM6wrgGnJE8H433v0EZmSXqDseU53F3vOnUQyy60z6SfQrIxrFujmQKRX1CHb1zpAhSwlsuK0HO/HQLXKdGWCwKT/HcQOBQkk@AmFPxXBkAC0oBQSsslUbwHQuVkbDcUeYop5QSTse3KMXBgxIA0X6DyNp3NN@A1m0sEC2dGSyJU0h00yKGGdFJEj@CULenBVNHumUfpgSzDT8vouiY87WG3i69Dm0s5hesKMXYlPXgAok2h5Kxev2s1LK/GQ9nDh0KnYEswxkO1qYU6UwziPBCDaQ0ECsCI7odDa55zQsquEoOCPLieStgcDJwBT9frDJxLRh4IJoWJuuP0ULqzl6RwoQYNw1rLxuG96EupKzXmqhBBn0r6cjSqvXEsW7mKLi0tRfPREvSYS0uPwLWJrkfoioPrEblUciGchi6KkSAXhlYoBvpVo9cVH/MoVsXmMMLe/p3VV4xKPr9aTRgVXTzT@IwBnaHHAGgVH4AnGisW0RmLyaVLKKhWb02Xfgd7vZPGwOoLInxhXBj8XVBhlcgAFecMcGBQQOXldpr0igPQLmAw0Ogog@hZJXVWPbs6a8bPrqMJjB0rGMU6FArSU3pae@AMQQ2JVdbyql6NxSqroHzUi9FUdEVRcioM42AkEvssF4sbnNpK1ITeUDk7iwJRBX0qjc6A8I0S6VgsIBXkAxUe0LWVqHaVg/TrsWosHoW4sWgChm7FaBQo00AiuFRobEtTBDo8/pITZicel6h5w6gUvze6U/DDQe909KPhu3couziOesBh3aHBtby@AEju2z6shoEzg1Y/qN5iKEen0vjcafFR0Q7@lA/2JHNEtfX54V75uEjJdAz3HHQKtY2wSdCVgSqDpgbSoDtsmtI8GBAb4GpMcoJzB5h4u9FgqsMITG3wTIS6iwZbgA1kDSmeDlO7vekiuB3I785UGQgJ@VPM2/SXhp8lDj43T0GSeyCxd04OpqbIeuegT7CG20XlWx3wAsBrcoV7NukRjDHybJ/GaDYomMBboF82g7kA27FVlIX@cM4JJ8QnRACC/FDbQk3CmoJBxC1rBEPiCM6nCNUfNVbU/nccGwanpvaSpKHMQJDjbJWpzdX/j7gipTXcSesETR@c/a7RAHk/je5MZmeAECRQMjk/JFa4gXh2cEDj@LvKCKpUw7CRfk2LxqlDy@0geWEsgb3AoAVUxUEqTu4Q1fZZA7TcNlDaHFkeH7VCCz/BKE8MV4nhOGmLjzOQy1BHxkz5M3ekwDoNGOGboCtjKJ8uYWX7who4NhJZKwNqEEUFrIMZ5PPIC2y0tbWf3l1M33nIgWI3vPUQbcNYZ4nbcKF12U7XaTtsBQCQNTWNM/a@jTOcMMrxjD60KOsdEWir7cBQf5oHTTOYM82uBuNNAyGTBK@9gV6AzS/0BGBBmU/2vymDGqJnUinIv/@Wok9QyBCW2TKiZ4NNAMQqQBf5BmvyG7PfGQ@m2Ml1xLyJR5OH1DD5TJYBKiTkSrTwdxQ13Mi5D7RzP6jpu@aVvUxjApy8C4@rp0o/pa3wZgMljMx4o69PiimkNyp8Ur8ouM6SU3IrmCpQWz3HM5IvNBDR@COhhqxaTHaT0aVoUlXxV6Ygli6xZNO8SKKUmmAelc3GXNwj02wkMRQ7N@Y75pLHD1xAmjP42PQDxeRPnwZBzNnyt@NxFOyUuyBtnmno5E87Q1MyGx2HyWcwxAiXTIYOogNjZRUoDwogjkuCaGJFSPKcIQzrmmbX6lnePs3Zd20cu2gkvDWUWiJ0B@TNBMGRZYJCziccJp0MzqtP@ii7zeGPQZITVhjia5ykA7OZXJlge@o4AxhXukynOYV0QPqeCEg6br@peSNAwGOVqX93/X7@2eFuuXa0dfqkmBy6g2TXqoOMaJq1Hgxmu9AcFnwwbzhDWAbesWynZ0GJfJTvzrvHjuNx5QEXDu73iWBEH8fBbu1gf/t46/hrkTnq0a3esGtgHvPLMwABjhOCuRVNw6k7oFvYw4WYQLk43D488LF88fxgf6u2Wz46PA2heTPsWoY@SvbP24sK9AWCMF1LcdIfdpvTKzo0TJ2aRRDCBsdcBQZjU6aq8KuiH08UR2UaBqCKjN2jquIssIHz3AOW1lMbG826kcuZ2WZjbW29ZbSazbW0nsu0cpl0JgU/69kNk70ncFU1RzRzAy4@K4ITSJgGZJ4eurbmazgwFG2AxjKem68g9JbMNTIZc31tw9hobGxsGOn15qqRzq2bZna9tZZKmVk91arn9NzqrZkLZQNVq8lbj2aAoNXhZAEFgvBT4DHVHHjmQde7ZM10Op1tZFobq@lmJrXWrG@kMrlmXV836htmqrW2qqf1ZiOt5/24OKMKUqIDFYZapQ2qqR@k6hAYk/zONFzFtMroL0MLgbO8iiKm7y8j48BBBKxhwFAsIuPUrPDPoL@/hIxTNMI/i/49XECeaLL0GngKwBwB4jqyNqj7nhvoGawgT62tgqgU8nNe@OJIAvOVnrpG5Je4Bh0q35Wuk/@F12pNeafJ@1zFrqw78V4lb74CPb32Kwp7I2gucIBvjfDxleu5@G4EzQUO8GU4Plzxno9uJmQeaIAsS8hwhXwurpmAOYABpnXCFF5Vn4TlKGzRkrpIa27wwkgB7g3CzVfLa2/4akVNLJYjN/MGcgqa2IED@vOBhfP2rakWIwUj8DNJ9qcRpieSJiHpyTIJUy/mr@/IYURcGFj2uUMD58BVS2l6BrEEKHrn3ZsxWzDUoJ8p0BuZuhnC@69evUU/cwCw052dmaMAmvYUXT90tUbymB44ATovB9NTuVPJ183WEEZBybplo/sOMHUjR5Ctet1aBAqUwM0H/nMOWJ4dD2EkmtbWNN0f9uLSCchsPg97un9IgHWDBnHT8/9sivjecOBBLPH8b99tQiXcrKKOMaaxYOCo2eYl8UdrYY2JqPhCP/Nrd9LrE2HIdRfKhoFLrkY3cMxHTbWvqh1j0MMhl6huYFD8AU64hdd4zvlcjP@cn0ieEZGn1xmYbfVYYw40wc4sifDEaJDddYwmkYEPhS2TIg2wsnk1mCM@KAwpPNDzLEpozsoFm2wV8DpDb8h/cXfAXdVo9fF7WxMVkKmMUddNUJGNumXeUukD43zYdFTQ9KjImLHsHNhJ6WmyTm11jXPurKFzfvF5AQdWuw36hHguArvswNiGBqXJS3rcxReuPXT7ah0qy4OGQ2/UFHq3pDDo8t9FIJbYPxc4FlPN6tLPPSo9YC5iF1DpiNC4pUkNEc2aIXPXqI9xqN75dC7DBEnBAZlTbMTjqVXs9oK13/BWpMXxsa@k@Bsb82PzzVScJPOGV0m@iUrlE8hUZrGt6o6KhY7L6hldNd0MORdKdH/qeOKaA0rzNmqja7jAWp6oDvMCqo9@bmN37JkaMOwaTFy3MPskO/4WgEWryUJsiVbdcLqWi027u0iCzi7ATdLE7Wz0E5qStuYRtkk6k9tRA9d8ueA0PFzKXcBo95ByfBUV16lDnKM5i4jWcC7xu1C16DgXJv@d39G9m5ure0gstUssYTXm9ijNxl2cituB6Gc@Hc/n5strdOf6T7cBf4ojPEC7J1@7Vtdx2Qn93kaW9gCi8d/5HB2moGXYKq0Hhd3zo4lM9ZkmZlkX1KvRbTvdbK6dNOBnYeUPBy3sE8TzvtIvkF66frf08vUjx9bFc6HYP08Ozu@qO1qaGOCifch5Sw88T4SJRcnFBYSRBO7EmV@4vVSOYmpJPl5eVAGDRufSGPvPX6JnWURdv2fpj0nfBvUPI2zkwOENuA7@y6S2dntqzfuJpxto1@8qRKhyz7smdGT0e6NKWTqlf2IMPZW6v7BqdYfm0Jwrqw7rb0zc337LKOT@mUqJYiyL2U6cEcK5zgDqnRg/3ivX2Ifj260Cxuha0Mjv1HTmyrs@6Oh9HHIfgeMIHTcjtu1hf6pyp0Zx9vHtlOv0/ZbtNKcyiSGfKpFyd@tTU4q8a9L31sEVHwzi2lZxLZVKCf0mNH899XLboGs1iPvG4r9TCZPPJOUJLM6GDELO@WlMplKh6q1zV8VJzftJp/SiGQEC3thI2pZtemP8XVQl86Rt3XG6n1KFIHSbFupvoJXiws9dVXlDNxK7wdhk7sPFmZN6a9GsB@@QxOgUqIcD79u4ITz1eq9qVnHJGlppe@b19nmg0ETuXalAN0@TS3zrRHex4ilmVHQtp63f2iK5OuvUza7BH6Ps2m34NrTVW/EFKovQk2ltC9fD@ArYZEU1MiO3@mMgltWEQU7H7Jn0esvowGi@Gbr@YyHQyMHvnGCN1hsXxetbIChs/J1abQupUp5jw7DMMwZtE8c1XVwVF76LhLM/qz6XuPs9o23yc1W3Sc/JVAduHeajwYlz/qRHnu86a0A0vvXjdlaAxnRujl3/ORfh03ED6nPYu3uqbqbdN2ij0l0NXUvOXUy4Q1e0O07H7pgdvhMoeFvUPIAjPX4i7rZCQP7bnQYj@RTepRSmbNfpdu9DWZSPXFo6Tmtunsp4TqsJUT8J79ioQ4B43DkFCH09EYg6/UXtpmMOoctyHc/pmyq9LQLt4mQR/10kRf3FnV92FurWGQKgiP/8ZfHfOTZtG47X79Oj1u8OXfqhqCodr5tXlXuUzH24wvL4tiPOt2bbqTc61l1ZqpuGZ1vnSX9GiL/eOrLth6hgMXUXvbWuBcQbjDXkhmI4/AQf@4uqVEwu8W4rcMyv4zzbGQ4GY6SE5zjM7TqXE/kwvX8imMblqw/oWJQDsTI4J5i0AdxZ5@8gu2UJRCwkLmQwUsJR4VbNFCgs@sIZpantnaHWsbrKfxbpRTPlp0yF1m8/ZUpUbHugyUErNHML/lP8M7UYPbezsjvDtntT3PEJ@yaoWPgzt6a32nimeaaieaVCD2TY4rGI3uluErdvw7MGNTc0b11dydy6vEJwelc1HAseNXhAHQ4XTpt1rb7Lf5naSs9VGG4uId@EGs8fNov6aZotvhaCrrs0vZ4zwENEoFKojYHpNnAqHSUy15@49LGdNkhmtcsmwD7s3CLcXLWeW/1Bj6d@9cxsG7i98sDCnZbdOVwBWGcXr@9C@p2h4VrfGTqeORff7AL2XeieGm2r8WSK8j4yn6JiDx5/TLE9et0k/mXHcun8hu@4Zc4JmYyzLfJZDfT9eaO1men64GD07dMqIUVJ7P1m6j7z94gHDlwwwHBjblrzZuKdPo0bx@S6bRLe8mhmVjznctX8TQC3JX857PWHrnjMT5326YSnqHvn5O9eWiAW1bcgjVnH6Hrzp7FDM7Ogc4lOcuJcpIV/Y3WdNvsml2KgokGnjUr5HIbbhu76yPCgRdhzGJjSvudCKU56qANesLfAE@YqUy3b8m6f4PE8A8ZI/hMLwzsbPIWYPMBf7fGnYlBP51Pk4FYNBvr2caOLh@I/dSTAxS5w4QkdWkdncG4@zPciGXNHIPR7F9u8DI/Xbl30yWOX6thDT8Vd/rf1Kdlb@5Q8G@WyIdZgynfKT5/HwhxC21/v0kNNGAgO3e544lq48WCG8SwblLXFsnga2h9N7Jpk0uCYNmreEWerj6enSOTvOvNGPEdj6H3uPWSCDmTY2zUbuPJ4Z9rPnKegukFX1geh2zs2ccvAjCyZHxGjHTgNowv0ad6ZzAmhndNXTAbXRt@sQ/12J675utg8xLuGZyzQnWjikEaAgetOXrG6dXPwhmYEQ@5Fg9rpDD0xRzQMWcwwvBWqXqPBFW6clptqI7NrO27fcWz@S0I4BQ/96e3CBroH@rn/iruG@5ener@5g7Tp0h5e8O0mZpMf3FtU3IFZd7r8F4uwQBzYFt9cYAws000eWPZwRH5MBd1t/jCHb@NNaes4zeF2oLFdWjDGDnb34mY1vlXYnRlJgUp8Ybi05D9/TDO1k/j@u4o6xqDh4NqZcHziylnoSNgdcjzYKs23JtShUkYg0IzG0LcrcEdWu716j34WjklCNX1s1vHIXZ3Oj3rGaJ4SOX10THjOHN7yRRo2/CxTjmDUE7u7I5sdsk1T3OrTDwn0y7ls4if3zDIb74zYHbI0aEU0l5w0aEQ7tyFNb4IDNadrql4H91gmPW@RwHhmnQ@b91jr8hdQhj0T16ynV24WMpXjdogjnPmr9IHAHZhi6zbuEoSm77tR6qpbC1kW0cP/4fYXSeiYa9k1PME/HKltEGd37wuAzA8Htnjch@2OHNdrWaPDPppxcgaL5AsWKwNR4MGbA7pWFhUC6tMedvl8Rzu0o6vXpPEdaIMtB1xdEuGeqZr2hUomjkb@cuXA8O3ILKzD2c2h@h27Qy/dYD0QAtS@S89k3z3aPzg81fqufsvMIW74G1pdXN2jrPh@UEByLZ6iPqG9avdcrFDhgatxU4@5uMWqaL9j1E3PSBoLBzsYanrzNb8np08P4pOTy0zZ6QycnhkLB@@cnCQg7@yLk7nB4dh7wOItZ7Qw@n5Z12NzePC5TWuCi@TenJQWYTo1YcgKHPWEH6K9U2tqOH2zeTrumy@gS0TZ694z@ezCQj4zLqw2NiW2sZBQ1NrYhpZd80FewHAcD0XdPi750gJNFjT0Bj1vlbLiEBXZewosg7gJcbwP/KyBMCHgar7xMnEWkro2/1QOeBqNxhBn4aBMGiNARTHi8VhMErGeOJesh5aRMJJLR3rPrX6BpXwn5rID2gvBo1EDhS0bbLPI9PUUi8UK3D4IsDq036FZYC3LR73lulbbhiz4OSDTTmj2hVuNchkMkTwfb6XClq9G@VRev2ZFJudlVq3yHOOHEimP@mSX6ZhHrywb1eJyVFWjy9EzO89S0QDc7LrmfHBjChYyiw@R4YC@3GabQwbXAmoWuFkb6LLRZFTHsJtQnYL9ofwDbpyFW/45xa3ef/mHTWFJiyzG9SzX6AJB0BgetMSOc/mIp@uTq9830BIX4rjs4DQ@pq7ubDH3EqfkuQEtqK7ne6c5YZZHWN6DlyM@URvkgnMOrhbjEWOPMwbPTXBcVCQcxPILBWPXYc8GZbHpdVyNnVh0eng4mJwHEvYIbW@AS0LNBNtnTRN31dKhcFoB7TrOOR0Uw5z85R9yY0R0NFwc2fWTJyNkoRTxBLhOFoAaDWcIufaRvDMHjgBRkMhGwxvifgOygUf@MTwwTVaSgNtV30YQJcMNBe1snTC1zKJoXQ9tehSslrK8dfz5i0qqWvzAeknzv303GbsShJM/UzeyrpxgPkjhGhkrHJyB4ElolMnLI5knGJybt4RkuOT1gZYBOZPh0Xmfxxyn7zcbHO6QWbOAG4W5EAXdVM@@saAemYgjhjUvyVgQHdC0sf8lE4UuNDB4jRFq3uqKy8qQL4GrJx7LQIJocMkAFzcqRyfJ0fANRlkesfeM@kgY7@iZFLxxQnbR1lKvuO2fuVgNn4VJ7pr1Ie0Hv0hr6UyRirNcK26WyAX6lIM2zyqvzkbplHo2Wi9XYQQniHp2Nvoslf4KqO4MINbDJLa88rPdq2WtlHr/3jXGTJavowV@dgfExPLV0f5R@eR06/T5CdTCtS/a9vgJPl/WIBfRodyO0yVrckAXHEp9gvwJ3iZiEO2VxmJS@PgkgQpay6q8zJ0h0TQV@47o8@K7Zij8JoCQaS2LSUHPAFxgELMh1bDwwz7axGMirrDrRVxmYf@BDSggDJ6QmiNLiVQyKwKxVCDWPUnFFhf2Efe7D8XuxHI72R7NBUGKBelVgnBexLkkuP6VlLtvuO7fv9wcy@3lJphbyg2gga8fZ29r/@D5cXk6mt/Jk9QtbmTEuWEunLGl8eGYb8iMzHWIiLiFoCgzmSLwV9GZcXOqpndpQrGEcGz0eGTiUMq/LE0YEyhTRIu@VaGFKArlAPUbVERmjzXDWCmURb@PDqG74kUMhMCeHKD2M67JAnOELNNq@PGLgVgFufymd0RCXMjrqBtWfxJ@i8OiYR89dHmbW9BVBb2Oy@A/1Cv5rnSVjZjozvQqU1kavl3TbkOBfdhYgfdRbJkTQl7meZeD/KJFUchT841Bq3Z0XEccB4Zeumv0XV8ZjLBnjmfm2duhQyZHfGES6BdkzNbgBoCparlZWzJlAsMFUH39fovw7e@dFFE746oZyfcwzw1t7KgAiNviFUYBvAHarOantblRTE5yR9hf9LtKmvlyhb21QEtw2YXlWjB2oEpooY7TBUmJpREFR3vOZGyGbXVd0Ema0H2DhuJhVwvKiUZnSPlBUtVmcgR4UgtUxgSTJYR1izft8UFXeomDmdc88jLBEWY3hDO6uaSqQLm2ZfvGm/NozZkmffLMGwxxi2gpeiOKn4U8udSO1@uGAOdYJj0zkx9/83e4NdIzD9w/FO5Rahvefl28tcD9G36IrsPbPwve0vD2I/72KolVdtME4ySfgTWNhadugTkfyzcKhoLBN2NNBQqqHKv7xf4RcxtoHRkrtAdD0kldoZjxxynM6gFnXFBFIzhPYVKPEzxKBcd3wFzAJKjjoFpD6ZmDqoLW@PLJJGYcF/M02qtrjvj@GTLO93aIRmlBE0tmM9k1PQmZVC98hGQvqI1HBznCWCwPglG6sPrF1/UG29zcZLLbMLpmMVvgDJJcNl6tyq@DjC4DrMRHCxUGcSDKJAaElUQ0ZdmI6zGMir1ZVI@iYGs6nN9AJVTIASAx9LZ9CyOgczqCVMDMtjnySG0a@6MgkNq2E7JG7SNSARHHjaZTZ9vk5DggzkCHWqkWrgb5JYLRFExensexlVfszDuzq8KELgPu@9kc/rXB/U/m2NXlnIUWlG4adFVmzbFiadjjE9vBifw9yC1T0sn0alLPxkIcKgtUkF9s7@8BJbRwkBgN03rj9N2tnfL@F4dHJzcMexFkdBYsyqKlzfiZqiUq1cARDfI9TdTtveTJ0@09n5ThXE2m0hFisjd6NpvzUpvN6YLUX/KTlzfTpoAbCemp@yKmeTh1j84Y3MQ@CU2GAHf4wa8bqSqxq@tKdbN0ZkduJP9@nrHmiLaCzAWuM5dMNUdns4lZDC5mOMWLGVzNNyugo00BPGzqOecTCwXCIxTAwX0sIAEkLelDLRKekIFDPgM0MaWT5jdDuCT6@CwRmdANchSCPPXvkMCmNbH8KEwedgy307XqEnTgTTQDyg0W@RZ5AlNHmtvvWp4Sk2gKpIhqEAgxRdwkMcqPNNoBoJDBZsKVYLdZUfTxxSRoBIAvejR0O@zI6YfmtnZN33UM2gjbHfLlYZN9MewBXIsexyaKWBP0ExUiA6GiQVb5qBpaljCiOIqjoUpIr4KmFEXBtV4zo4xiWsccNa02CHAlloCW/pkOalVg5gELTYYV7SjIOE7hz/HAXZikn2RLczRBblQMzbKb5khB41D5Kuin6B@9fHkRjck3eIAMeu74JgBnLHv6DdHwRIuYWMWcaWwbwfURM6ZXNzbQwBZarIBqgRRPvMEBOKF/Ulo9o8@UIZmcdZnG6FU5U@yE6w1iTC1xqzU2i8dpVA0PCgCtGUFb5CLGYQrOQyrJItQO@rp2Ex/vrD6r6JpWBTclEmPLOKO2A105zkXFJBglQZQ8oS1i3bI85ohzr8Y5D@JguEQ28BjaXZ0TTJZSaY7ZQVpQqVnpYch22KQFcqpubORFbUyLmg0GbHFTymtJQDtHhPhaKtBXGCAAquFNAnjlBK4/gVh4/KVp2yYQCHimZ0AfbAyByQaxhH91TGJieZ5SiPAsPhEWDSCj0xbpy9GrLm5SWE4WaHKmcA196usz7FRbolsdJ//npJYsXCnL3eI4CYpOrKQsd4p6fHUlHl@2V5RlG7v6hw9xTud6GTSJmgZDpBEAqcvdWAH4GTSP4rJdWDY2leVmMb1CMeAVBmlXEOGDm9Sulo3r5PJD6KkT4DPgjVdZdsmoaUrT9GvIH7aQ5WQCeOYKbUDSvTGY/LIVj2MetOUaZuBD8uwkTjL77CRJ00cFoY0m2z3R3GakalATN27N4QQU3qKiQbCnUbCLgyQ1H3hij351XtgC3YMn/CWe1WO0Pdh0w@q/PB1yf8Ei5F2U7M1xE7LcqiwQcKQAEfE1YcRiIEx@8YuInmWysvwou9q9iEczqQL86IV1lmGfLZ@l1yIs8tgwPBiyJ1euznZz7QtmttLZt6pasVra2@rR@dHRV6Nx7EyJRnYOX8n6GoCusw363vezztILPuzTPpHISlKKJFf0h@vJ5OvXr0HlxU@lpJV8EK0aq6jRakVZFx690vr6SiKbW0kcP47WIC9Q3JiSTsdOmGUl2ZnVd5tN@DodusVJifAPe/QI0wMH/DPh1xu1yDnaMtvtYdkYc38rMsTHnifiPv3m5cuX6HhJH/buWMSPcIwCXSRfMzIRymQ6lf7LP126Tlwd1Tb/8nu9pLmEj0N8/PD6KbpP9MxnS0ufbW@vrSWAcNx99M3R11tbW2u7icxRJfNoTU0tbf7Fny8tpdOb6eRS1XX1arRy/pWcTq3J2l/@frR2dPQd18W6w88q08GJvzn46iyTYefsHXzOWwz/yf2uGXIb6K633mEHCcpykYRNNJpZjZ68imL9vIvouh4Z01@NirbE9NKj9f/@48O3ES9SSidfDuDpRd5GsrkId4ID3lb9t4tIKbKJYNnryDhZLBbBuf7f/x3EL30BeDBkvAk/pYyPKzuOlNQiRXkfKWXBoafTkO7/893vSpHSCDJRKu3vsXQpvSLYRM891B@Sy/Y6oGCcRfTc2uFjerXMx4fpTHoT3baJt990YDiKQkbX02dMVJ4uqhCLq@Mv92AdcGOdOhHmg07qnPkcxV5GiD@AQYhHuFt4ENtwj5ezcC/PDGNlPb6WfmwXXoY@Uy@/@s8xXjKWXXr8ejeZ3CxBP4@ffP7xWU00siRbz8mO8xin/grsQPgW8GfkqKoD4PA9I08VP4J8kVwxUeMk8tuYH8ImbyzsFRGUZEFz@iXgyvj5q//4Vz/5qx/T30/o@1@kiL@FSK1cVEv@B/hHLg3kqzPxaj9lT/nHtuEfvv4r@qAHuGwxMxkJPqUS/tC/eCMXPWf8REgpeCGISZSFcMyXV5SuFPmQTDJsAezCL8zjpfxSLp/Np5M1v3hUDJ5zcjwNlW5SPlGeR/BZgj/6h0/wir9L5CO8CeTmZ4mV7vOZ2wFIkUqkUq3yNl0KV9Dtn2MNmU4Tb7Vwl3IhRVSQUvH4MTApE7wNn7P4HZ/n8NW0mnhLahOsESnyK/@UJBa5gk81rl5fV7RX8UJB/IN2Vwje8MNdkLXqtapuvirF4xXKYqUk8hpdc6JZ5/GmyqolXgD61WqvNgF9fLOyWXR26KsRj6jVV6XK5jQO@Gyq1dLjx3Ek7WNAUFquMhhXQG1cb16Xriub19ebm/C/Sb/X4gm@15s3/ukx@SyAmYRXsf7PKsnSWVI0ylIV3rVkCX205Bk4SvAEuEpFilwh57BKlQzzFdWKns1UVUYNZAWEVzKvr6RXk5nRZ9lyGmSAi@BpWU6uoOM99pWg7WxIERw3bPDhwwZ5vP747f@F37OP3/4beIWs4Q2IFFp/i38H7/DvrYd/pw38O36Lf@z0Hf4de/j3tI5/Ry7@nb7Fv606/p328E@KFBkDDW75Uaqbukjp5/o5OCyWAgW6k@roTeh8WMpkqXFqzFI9R2@Cy4S/FLisVIul2ixlp2xdh0BweCzloasFjzb8tQDLAP6sVAqRpy4YpNLFLo1sXNPzfY3FzqQKi742Qe3SdC2lZa1aNZPtv61Eq4VI8uwsyXVRll4rkE3z62vGarXys91aLYnt4eypczj5PzzshV9v/e8dOk8PnZ4D/4eHh0/PQKSV4o/j6mP4FEvxTfF4FCkVHp3lVeRln6sjyc1HZ6VVFd3ZODBqGv3in/iZYIRnaelMgrH6y5eXBep3C5cXhcsCOYJX7qgJAAHGHRCrIPpr8IF4Zy@T1MdewueC8NIbOi8h0HdxR/Ll5RlqlDB@CP6BHOHXX8G/9f@v/6fPmVKpxqARXF1vKvSJ4V8sdnV9dS1@SzFFES/KJvyhB7xjlKvrEjoJ6ApcFSVWjV1fcz/4VWKbHGEJ09gsUeQJIAiPSJAmpct/lF/tE9Pmn7MoKE4wslbEsuDZ2SiVihXq4BOsDRjvaYUpVqC9N8t1XBWE0aQeI4jMWqGgr3B3ei1dKKyJl/VcoZAT7mVF2bj5KaUe6VnQDtbWYrFCISVgYdxY8J2AwnSNRgEbeSESw8zylq@kcHaSbjOJynn54UNF3H/zqN@PPXyob6Tevw@8arWmNajV0H/1/Xu5JuM2neJGBt5TuffvQehEY85AeebwBWJF1dln6RKlsOEMoFTrEMz0ZHqSZsdwDc8bKO@sfkLGPayuHCML5KmUMziL/vxH3/veWbSIGzfId01HBJgKy2xuZtdKpewauLM5KLi8zHcCKe34hh67Xk7KvLhMXo5GRJCeW4@R73UUw1lkkz0qQUN18cOuriNUf2wtE1PqYzN2BT6@n76xwT3ZWlbJxTfEX3EpxkorTPxVKpXV@NrK@srjKmg8Nz8oVAtXRjGaTEavi1dGHmexrgsNcdMFni4zHj5c3QBi5lKFM6lW29063arhJZm4Rg8dIkNPktASrr/2B9EKTTlmNqoVLFj1LBrNFx5Tteu5DItECwJOjYK0Z7kNKn/EdSWrhcdMR4hUigS/K5E@09dXoZOFPlbq006p9RRr4mLzgDmt1hJ4QrWxOu4LcM1u178Y5NIZdJuXVtNckiJHB1s75dNEGvSVSHpvayeRPnm@HdHxNTN5x2AWWUWP4/LW7uFziHF0UN46KX@@/6L8/Aj8XenNO8M0DXNompe14fDyLV4eYdbMPvhOPjWzYbnGmzdGnz4wZOFy@ePPfvDxZ//Lx9/70cff@8HH3/vJz7/9yQ/g@4fw/RF//ujfbmTw9@ff/rM/@Pi7vwee/wW@/xm@f/rzb3/7u/xL738G3/8a8vsz8Q3B8a8EuH7959/@@Pd//u1v/BS@/0J8f3rz@5t/Ov/7k@8v/mK8H//B7TA/@nfw/SOOy4f90e9yP3zegP9dDvcbP/34W/@B//@F@EPn7338rT/DH/HyT3/6F//14/f@Uzqd@4t//fEHP/r4/R9//P73Pn7/hx@//4/TH3/7X@up8M8ffPzJH/@PP/mj//En/xv9/yH9/tF9/j/@9J/@9b//6//7r/9EfP8Uvv8BXH/61/8JePVv//hn@P/jP/7b//wz/P8//@Xf/vH//re//q/I8Tvc8f/@i3/Lf//mez/4m@//87/53rcLfn9w6@@39/D/9h/A5/75vA@e@5TrU32@/aXy8/ehxiQV4AG6pIOlQX3dHps0dfHZKC99xiKlFfyANK7k0rn4CmieKxsbIJKr5L@JIEyCdvqTf/Lxt38N2P@3ABm8/a/wBv/8BYJ@SC/sq6@mAlmcpkPU@FdfYaAYQH4VhvoheLxPgh6eevweIL6iYP5hARik@38QGMAxAebDTWeAYHC3J/f/@bf//PcpIIiL3r82hTLle4ehlxH8vV/UH2K7n5QmDP1DFB0ff/bdj7//jz/@7Hc@/uzXsXNQ1zYSWwno1G@f7wXAzD3gEDB7HzgA1HEACQP@JSkNjqVNnKOU9Pjr15D7JXDBYGtFyqzCm6SXyK2jGyLG4Y2QjEZx/IV/aW2D4Qv4jMgXniwOQdtxvLw9Lo2KEEageOs7Q2cpB14jnGgoAl6MxOMkajkYxrDRNmGBmMX4MautFEc8Yhw9SoQB2UZCr2NZT8vxXHEXEiyOdhniQuRx6TU8XxdLueKohOg@UBYAR3wbkgQovFQ@Pip9gPci4QR4abT7AbKSK8bjpRz4FLGQcUotUaM09QwVjsoeZ1Ru9GcMd10@egxNRtZzMp8IAVIyAY2/8Qk0AgI4hJ/FV0Rx6N930ncF40M9jYg@3I@HP0Jvii8AAK@q4mY9@Koq5uYxBI84qjglC484xwCUi5P@5KMED1KG4lKc6jdOL5A@5OHTPpsoKhAdFmd5eRlcmyV5Va4dwugRhmmD87zrGQNcTCQVMs/k7IaM3rjzie/pXD6iYebK7gr86vBfXqJ9zFSWwoq0HMU5jCjPWpx9Fuffx49X2GdQdnpO/CSmxledNSfCi7kZj8tpSLLkwNsKFTFOiHCOgf7j0quIxCJU99BYEvwXHlqR/ENNiTxeFaX45B1nHkUMTUtoiYR4avQkD004NAoVT22ZVEbGRzy0ZM307BqLSQpdjxbDGmqYpIxJT932tjOC0UZClhN6FpehYmLS5jSfxtYqlfMp@P3ayeeLH/S1dQme9D7Ea9rEhWHAN3hZvba5ifVfulJpZgmdoLJmpVJJrMAzXSqdlE8B/PSQ6emUxmCkcrW2nl7LrGXSq9lsZj2tr2U31rKZ3CpI1mwqk07rG2trG7mN9euAWo9BOCXyK/XMZukf3fj8T/9o3me@L36k0ldspNFk@rVU6hb5TtBlXI2Xz1Jygaa5iJbLlVQC/9Krq/AL@UzomfXq0lL3SsVin9H2wyvc7wBZla5U7PgewIdJDyT2ALzgA2ngeiQTO0j2DwtitwDetsp3DMh6BhgZ6uEMOJmjgxq9uroKfaXI0jffeKxUghGHur8nRaANdpi/Pq5aTa2j0SWpzeHApNA2Y7v7L/ZP9g@fabv7JzAO@JqlV1OaFLm@vm4Fqzr0arLDw0MJhR8M7VZ1jH/dYMPhkELr8H49MqR@@FPoT3@kdFpNr6qruqqv4v8djjT@3x8@Df9p/IVYq2mJH7Ls4nkef95sA9u5tMnNhpTwij/HaBaDm2CZErtqFptOg87pFFrFSlVzoUIKTa3uNMea641h2Ne03H7XGBej9a7TOI/6gRbeDYQH3opLyUFSw73KSiv2KJ1dzy/hPjryYUqLgV8G/V75ngSW2cg3NT/pp1C9EDOdT2cz15vCLFgJMo4ZKGFyVyIXeRuG79e4QTVvtKC8Vw2@sSMvpzM5@fpxz2xaBjtL4emnq7lg2ax87cNBQjhMxMG70sNLOXCbcz51lootiJuCuJA/ypa0KQyQlGhdvgIttIp3FVaqm75pkpL04cOHEW2Fye/bntgTk17LoT@TUCw9hP7@oc6dmezEmULnKZqReQY1AnLFZge4td1z2KnDt1Bvm40FEDsdg65u3Bk4MJL@5WG2DfucB@1a3J5FEPTEQIPWbs/yOgsgnvd7eF7RHPyDYSj36pBBZCAOsA0/g67jzANYZ8@PFpTyaWB@CrfPkP0pAD/e//zJaeh5Wt7aeSJl2fbhs92ZR0YAZdhBee80eF3noX7UTIDi6/LBweyreECnVaCpkyWWWcfts/6LziKGZ8iJmlypFqCheteg2uUKTXv4SH/4UN/MZo8OgJobAJhla6Xc6noqn19OMmgLL6BsxW2ypXGe7@O2XNcslUdHAzxmaG@sQak/qJtD9pyEBk53XBYGJmg96by3LD3F/bobOj98ZrkSnQHFawHxClBPQlMXTefSpnN19e7QZMM@W@gJD/RC58Bqd6BXvnR8AKluGAy@n/qB@OG5FiDXrR4eT4P8boR054DjBhGrxVKSxumzkcvkNlbTuURuI7eW0bOZTEJPJ/T13PoG9IcpPadnc5kNPZFb21hdg04bQjMb61IE@jGrlUyCZqTLMjzzgNZu4E02m3glkKN1SlKET2ayd4oRgwoP3odMNiGOjHcqglTFIwkrVlFOr@F5oVWdAUaDNVhkb28ntbcny9v4gmstOylZbuJLJpdKrW/LskkhO6BYpGXZ4XEgCMA8/pJKbe/I8pAjQLtYstzBl3IWh22ybOHLztbeHqbzBl/SGB/AznkIf@n6L@sAZuPL6iqN@2T5bYAO4LZ4QmuU0zK@YJoYssdDdiBMlj/385NKAYZjDscxPPHLurUly/v8ZWsLQ76ggmd4Vr/Ely36yPIAXoAJZbkNjjZ2ArJcByeyoiw3wNUYG@CHtwahrSQbmp485gRCEsnyiKCNxrkMoxPhj8k8efLE6HhNs80/4wF/NiBrEGKNhuW9@uef19vt@mC8Vf78GEO@@OKJ8WY8HNTbdRGtXoOPA3Eg5Lw3nv1AHvdrNaM7N@RLCLFnQmrjmol5qxlvIU/i08ZEerUvIOQLCJkzITzi2ODTA9A6frZ78Nw26hTifyiEnqN6XS4go3rjvokTuNhmzm2QBYme0Rg4BXwfFZdYVIkmxpVsqlogf9ZTWOwqVbjG8JZCN9OiZg8a4NW4MiqmqjBqXU@Lc02KfDZKZyw5sdR7pG9k8kvGIz29Fh/l0fC504qyqKo/UvSHK@@UZ6BrrK7l5bNHj1S5olcfpfVcPrv@amUoy7E8/j5aXc@/A@U/Cho@/sQq69VH65lQlPX1uJFM59dxA1iscA0U8aAjqg89s1ZTlEvTOI/FMMfYvYNKRcVlYyqqVWgpo8SoyDPGxrHCqKgXuNUOlrqBq4lmo4Z4CSTH2AZ0o0epPE6iK7K@kZMh/WRSicVQKqEcgefrl/4aX/AIOaac/KOxvMpvkNVz2ZiGp2RqTqtGt@ix12HIyQK59BIPttGhdn//KY083bx0iqMe7A5IobLqeHU1GSmA8T83eMb4VJi@viFJJaH0H/FbvAri9fMnOxqMA8QbmqHS9lBPdQYa3rTtTYVwE0m@1yl0adoTE3eVNny/HX7cXCuPYJCHyq4fcCCOOmnCcoR2@qRwpdZwPv47p@enp9@o12G0JzAA4hnBYzkFMsCAB9zRaJfVZEaxBC4DhtoK5RJIELskctRKpWKt2DN7fW8MZfbjfclN604Q7bu8MMFxIYp@hUfoRECtmLqewD8b9tg2B6Jzdn60WnEbjSwUbDR5aeLrMhtFRlKpiRa9tovbV8M86qDXBbNoDgbOQI7g4cRHdnFou0bLPDIHeC5u/3CZtZiJJ9AanddnZYTcQV36Wi0NmD2VD8VQS/XYtFfoFUmnfCegyBXt7Ma1omsYaSivYoW38DZYZkpT2449Wis0lW1Wi4FP6nXrdYulWXatQBc8KIgJxAFRDilixIqlLwExx3uez0NGBEucA05MaBlqxGpSiBHrW9eFdrGC0O/xZ1OV5aqqVt5XpVJBKoF0KYwjRtEd1vlVrKk6jMqzhRH46etrhQ6rF@uvRoVBsQ/jSFboQrWL8THfrm7g1mUgEuB59175@GvfjW2qmSL3KxCu911QJGparTiaVNBqsZKG0XM6u4aj6ewqfHUYVadxM2YindpIpHXQJ0DPgPjwXYf3NfgCDKgbaR3H3EpXgTGynEiNUpqe0E09oaReW83XscS5AuofESyW8JyyDVwDHsg8wLL0Ck8jFk@vdJWmw4xNlfgXpF2BCmkkOqxvJTqI5tg0uhw8prLVFaW7rCDM8umwX65U8/nyqP8dDFLUt4@y8fVU/F0sVlCWWKzomm@JwigYiQT9JeBmMY/A3GGvklqCQkP7U6@hpr1lfT2drwyXK6oOpUu9b2/KJbkKVXXNJPgLL0SCvlUAP18Gcg1tomNN/PqoT3dNqFZ9I10QIFJfSGRFVs5k/2SFEo2up6PRWLSAs2dL4C8kOonfKHQH0Yf6Ixl0PDkvb6QhfCLIb@SAj8GzuhS5lnDwymA0HrmSrq@uN8M70b5k47ERV/3Xh4y148sSS9IOEa0WYUvkUrUSzXFuFbfax1sFAb21I0XytFlysp@NnYmj8UxNLn3qvpT4ZukVf57htixIViJTcxVWFXMK6VUodDP0DgV0ryROVb5dKbkZL7HkmSTLJGP42nYuE@N5ZR8i1KrZzpU/EZF/iuNiphh53oor1diHZ1b3Kreq8rG1wiIfWDyp0Y67WvJDBHrBa6K1v7vyy9fpDFDfdnwPGEV7IMCh08xkZJzNM1@z/snGq/VXuVdPnx8@P9xjj1P5XD43M51/9jiR0KN6dJM9Br3dOi7DkOw9czL6B/sLvgU1Uojk@9HVtejqbNRiZFRc8zcvKHqppOqbafYIeJXlQb639Kyael/ijFeigGwaQj7@2k/XRps5eE@DfpwHmmbi6VJJX0nHIv2P3/4bPEJ5VX6xdcCiaNDi7/7899Prf/fn/5JWyqPXBfRLr65HABKdenY9cnXVv7q6hg8Py0SqEZ6ntfUYuPkuDj1SSgpvfV2PRVyVv0F2MxH3vbBwo6RTOQjbOeRvchaoGdmISJHc09fvGduE8XKp2W5baXIlkzfWR5bzMLiEf/YB50M/qEuvi6XlJDAATu5uYAR//m6lVCqt4MILi5bieBw4naH1n8p1oQpExQ@OyFZs@jPdFfzD91fcY8V14d0Phlece980WaakMxjFJZMff@230@ns3/35b57F3tfe174BQbuxsZHV05FfQD5uOaPnD8No/gZP26EjGL6xBVdGag1ZiuA9oi3G4f3BHA7f8IQ6t@@Db9IFahNE4hrQ0QDdWSGwFTxplCAtmo4lxwqSFKiapCUP2o0E4WAraJ8X2o50JT3AIOijWBFkk/Rgggo8emgYqFFzu8NBn3Q@heLp1QR7CFEghQdoSmKJTkgJAafqBZZcuRmVZ5lblSGtgvVM10VrUiB/pQcQ5QC4lC76YX0DT9khpGWDQNUQhPJJAc0KpF2FtLs8Qo18FSo9B0gwnjseyQY1WnqAR4ZIzYaul1mbAFBgMekBEADKoAjEVpVtstUYu7Li8cLE@NQ17nNDywOGf4ZHwmiIrYkH1/zIBYSzuIGJ4QCNLjFRww0z7Okj4Tj4skwRBgAYnd5QdaFjevdGBbjouLZCRWMPH05yVSxazRijEiF@tL2FBrMmloJuJADI/NHTZ828nGB2PI6V/WCa7YDiccoucJ1KjglQCw9T4eu1JMH/vZkWOXKmqiiggAUQ9cVbRQNIBpGR7LwOG2Q9LL0eY0HmG5D3BmWKjJAEQ8Kz0Wca2QJq8CxeS7@I@AYuJbyQOzR2EXw7e4iLgVwa4pVHeEKdCwNxPItfhoHCad/zYwexoChWl6Bb1gBGAbTE5JszUVb1GEZrBT6UD9rfll5juPUsE8MHxUJoNHphoAEJkc4SzVCT5S2379hkcYJO7@IGPbID5krcvgbP9tC@NMh2FE@F9rOFcsQNciHnk70omxvFcnlcXM6qD2BI69Mmwcy2RqZV0htM4UbecA7RDtDFKBJlGMZ@BtK43jV7kKUT02Ro9cDNJ5Nty@sM62Tm4KkFfNXZs6DbsN2kuFwpeWmdW8lTtM2nOi1QR8Wxugh7YXStwOKQsCVABsO61rnJh6TK1LlIl6WzCVD3EkDZyRcIm8f5VTz7mILgBIeC7zo81rkzlwjFXVLGsZvPVX1JqcVILSBjMAO8QOnCsEP0pc97SQwk3bHrH3qmU3jwrgUiF1omP/kUxaNPwZE8SZzOLtLJYQ0nvvsKqFP@WT10goppXgCEqkvYx4DQbPiHCLEVQ2kfUAdAbQ9aFloF8QZ5PF1bRHtZSgOanhDwNvuMrabpWnp@3lwcDwccWPXFaewQBlGxHK7XhIrR@GwCyBVonb0mhEXQSA5nP4zvcze6yULOhL3ZkkCHnQ6lVWS8WfgvmdALtg5u7wyKvgSBWcjhnJwsKXIc0MblmMxRB/Fno3Nul0iW5NlNTAmGGASpAQuqCtuGy20wCpMel5eXGlmVGQ4szXTRiKqLF8Ml@20LtFEn6Zm9vrj/wsLLi8TFbBOXyo0o4z2Cj0Z0fd/GwzF/SlILz7m@HVoDU4m23Cj2gRcgK/vtHh3Zx8P0LvHNnkVGhRsKrXq6gs3S1cSVz2Z5ZDM1F71GJIwhmlFinGgkAFmi3jhPtC6bBRFwQe0OkENlmb4nGnwb@C8913dZ/VYA4Xi0VdZ/r3fPG07XQdVD5jOmk6R5CX3Isf8q3vvWCCLZ5iXbGgyMsULhMYRGPlXGpN2wMfTuFAJO6E3YFbeLZI0q4@pU9FEQHfquYBF0gAf2pavbkXJzVBg@4uEjCB/x8NEkUT/ZyqjKNS/0usbiIHOj/R0fEtGMfZhrbk1rEkKYQS9mOkeBkOMpv2v4NooU26c3f4N6LPqMATxBRuwUtJ5XOavarnm5Uo0n28DTMhECahxQV6pE08tm4Ebqdy@6fced8rLRPA10PiLf6NXoCG7gvIJlDCqIGIPTy0IrJu2exudNeL8vCgwYUN2CQNQAtjzFihUC@6EUCIxTkSc05hmriMxUSckSQcIPtCJOek7YMKJqCBH6B0WCbEII81uOMJEthMDLAd4m6sOqdIcDGUKNVqNAyZmmwkVKgSoplCtV9bMJZEettDhbFD8cqqIyExQq5rWo/3D2lz45@y1oF/NzTwzL@4WCFG4q5giNPpqiuRBVWakYqlfIQXLF6JoD6KDKXA0VnTIks5L0RxM8HSwCN1aqhCq/EeP1Q6cQZFvOB6wwLhahiOMib5a8Xfgk5QQPorki2thnBBGfCxDAkZobzRTRRuFoo2KRCw42WhDtMpTJEWVyxKNw6NGCTFZFNBgkBeYwsXqqaAUNFCoZ8Om8t0SLnzJzjQs068reoNUSGDz5aU5kDnGB4CHUpJHPGtW5qVdCmQ4JrRkEyIg3EDT5jRx5aVbg6WrwFsgoTkpfRvE3wQZcVgCDkQgucMtUSsBkNNQFvV6OUz8AbVeOVyRZx11H9JfiXznhe/pf/aZnahpSn/ZMJWb@/kE8q0jZUAMNKRl6ag0FMg5YtshQB6gllw5T5ijP4J/0r1xN1rtOPdkzcI8E3s0cXMQa88cDZIrvcd/xDM9ZW8vzQZBF/PVcgLOQNXw@BrDatgNDjbDlO4tb6rOjaJCw4bRtyzUTePUrV8FNWtbnRqmlsN4rnI4rSWLWjw9LETVnIFRdazW8NqhWU1yz24rlA7OS@KohH0ajEo5nwRWKD3JIID3sKw7ee@3F7saJZiFFtFOrca4c9kVgFBLZYiCsGqDPQ2gHVBXmOpORINlrQ9W47ilkkrvj9Jw2qHdoixFjz6Dfn@DGDBn9PuUlwQwcouZDxjOpOSiNhBETUb/85Kjsy7RixIL46WkEU8RIsMEsjZGygznJ1RYmx6P56Z18en5Pwvk9uT2/NKqezTMfahd54KclvapMMADgJBurd2cjIUwf38jOVFYCb1SgeIR7Z7FJe5CamNMtAN0S4FoL@CMRvLlkkEVk/MUi@t9egX708n2rz8Bb1E7GIG96uNVNIaP0rr/kpwD4fgxlz83kAtbevWdaAIt28vdQVwB9lQSXjdZ@oGH2YRjtysGSh0B8B8/jfqMbfE@bkIo8cE6eBhcJdp5eXEW7tabZNcZmUxGQiRBev8THMDIjeXW/gqOgI6Hn8EGdAp1ULGwqGInOgfILWMZIXIQMRd@A4SBWwD0080053F9MPwy/IZpxyq7IZ59B4Y9GI2RTnEzA98f9MbeS2OVXfAg5yvsfXpN4FvNuggAdxG6FxCTZ2G3i81gJinSPHiGA1aaLTPaQ/G7L6fVv1uGnkejukkLlhiIV/VqesuO8qMat22o8xBU@T/L1nPux5F1Md2@eC7EaRzYRYTuf1oXcwIy7FBoNJYyR@9xaY459QyagH8272Qt6ldocgRrEJEnnWTSuJv0iJuEQeB@eOIH0Ap6IsG16Nc5Qftlwjkpc8sEopGf0Q1qL8AFtHLCEqOhb66dshKAk3w3gV9dBmo2FaTZupNmYSjNoAdNJhoCkxlSSohawem6rgq7Z8hZIZwzCQTI8bhPb8LEdY4DTEldRK5q3Eix6Ec2DQI6a0XxZAaEcbUbzu@Rwo/kTcpxH81@CY9K2ou@jeb9ZIMAAXsnxGP2FCMf3RjS/o8SuJQ8vVPDT1aL5oE4B5hF/JYoAKbDcoDXikpntiGJ6AxM6NlIqEww5xk3gOIkmXBL0TcE/t5zOb/iAQJyzXCFgFmf6VKcR6jF4OtBt@DY157TkvOjNy4d7tMtnYpoewuMwmAvHIfSghkei08KIZwxDaYUCnpBBlJv5@Tli@vT9BffIjkgdOJQqeTp9op5G@kBTofAKAFdj02bxRXy/vqZR8Aq8Xz4x8qJ83siOnxzlCNdYY3OyhUR9Hb2lUFjXM3c@8NoP1xDNXU8D4a2DPgivJUIbkumgw9FiGybWd/rTTEKhuHfPCseh2TfeKJF7Z6KRVBAtc0EweYuSoWAIN/7YbcUJxcOsTYkgDKykqryVBf0CyWIMmsi6kKbKGx9kISRzoIWbjXMT2XZXOAmOi5sE9RWLuiE/Lk@SJNe0mITIGhqVGBoeTz0YvJbR1MSnDV/9mCOcVFEQQShmkAqXr84n6O8O1999hdonwkwC8xTr@V3pTfX61l52JufdSbI3KxADE2w3Nlc5ClKYkBxGByHN/DZeu6Hi4xYOruTzRAPsM9q@T7ZgTHAH3WbHFhwXagmDi2nP8zR4nqcXE@qmRtK90HylRcOUBB5e8CCnk6Ldnlde8HlVjCE0kW10P7mCB9MVHK48xEcFGMyQnLdyPCeIa1uTtk0GS9EHRaqeZ1yQ0/JnUM0TTxD3tBQbLMOCx2HtePfw2cHX0Omur6/HRB89nuQPWy1Oqgb9OMdMO4yD/mDOsCWdQIPduHiN8@50i@fSmS3fkCVcWIMygBeV@Own2nhMyLKQPJ9puxCPw4YoKnCdT5qBMSWVUNUxsMu2BF09IIjpKSuGQOKrt0DvBI3WYjgnC9yBd57VatR91Wq4GalWE70YVo2/wh37RWQpOXQHdH0iNyd8KXFrLmz3kL18snXKTp@U2d7znS/Z14fP2cutZ6d4Kvbo@fbB/g6Db/nZSZlNZhTwg1cs4IAS6LprNsxeHUR2OpVa4xZidpz@mMsdZSfG/U@MHnviNExcj9p0jd7jDn/RbNMr8VhlGI6OxU3gkNGe5Xn8erIGoCPlpkmnz3CjPgPYOoxpezjm7TlNq2UBrIRj375luv5JKda1oAZB3vqnHBNcScLrHmgrEF31Rbe04TVfAI@LNIDGcCfXylkuj2A2NWEGZ/L5ZAqelo@fnrCtZ7ts5/DZ7v7p/uGzE7Z3eAyvR1/vP/sc6Ll/cnq8v/0cgwjw6eHu/t7@zhZ58AykNIbnnunettuyoCE4UaVxjkvcdB1q8BaedQYw0ODZpUHn8FwWHdoofSyja70zm9GChBfB8LN/tCbAgmvYmPkWlzL9NV/aTyA/d@kqk@UU26TUoLGUoL0VRHOFbg@NSuPCQ2/M8Eobs0DHkRVyT67KoU05Tctk8g7uOcG5b35qmdqyjxoSWgLciMrfgFJkZKE9Gk1sEsoSpNboOmhWi6fGNwWKF4z62N86UpCIYmLvCyLF/fv7Ns4H6YXAA/gePNIiWW/AAdhq4MEB2Br3QFV0H/eCsIyAGHqHQxTPLMs93vT6e7T@y9YDj22DRrE5kSdeb1SlBptcs2z1@l2ysc9neejqHMNtWBZFcQkebdR3u/79dXUTWB5korhtCPeqAaQMwqaFSw1iG5s9pIYNocANuO/HaHkuU4oxjZ3iZh/TtvjlBe2uYfMtTZOtOMR7LIc2KYpit7UV3ArQ5HecEwPiTR3T@Qji7Qqt0LxvPIi5fSNFQ@x5pJtl/C1ld2Vg@0YGfhk0gEidGuk0qKeiM5mIxmkJVlZcBzgS520/hOGBnZvDhjkVwb9d8I317l1MEDkxNU7y9x1S7qCK8CLGBF@zbDkDaOMkVnt4vgSlYKPj9D2L16EyXYLJ3VAAjR0bpPa6WJpKje6DnEnRduxQonXg4gWp1oEp75MqcTxfJA/El9/Wg8upaB8dZseoOxdmaO0sgYtIlyZOv4AizC/Ww96GLkoV@qc0kR0f6LLDXLG0u32mfnidQNP6XCzw66T8TYT8csQepgXNg9b5aAPiAPUu0dL8@xncYR1jiz11QlpiK/eRwTiwY8G47nGtEITx7cM3/fHwyKw/eb5/X@SxVJRMXCIP3Y4ykW4JVvGTTFCcKhN7PUKyEzILsl7xfRKEM5DXj/GcCNZCAShioxyha02n70UQIsQvXX3YAskibj4S1R3gj7ESbZ3wFUn6KOH6SL5StovxUiw52TnCQuRUfBGd8DHjxUiT/SfUX91At3s7OpDf90eXuzV3vHv4JGy7t2L7pLyp8cW4eLcUwnV/tB9uQcs7t18KLZQ9sRgx7yRvYgs4PWDOxHIk2B17e4qvb9QdtT1Ag30vzqAESEOpDW1aovZtXyo8QiyMZqIQnZzulo@PmczHJxAX5B4OGZpCDCLuJX5tBN89a9kk7LRAaQoGy4Hy5PtMbV0Ljnzc0pjnEm@BqBA6SELQIxAW05c0ktQTPQupELSbngSiT7np3F35MsitCMTXaOwUhFdkooYFBZTmFjPCOx/LDW/qFnRLcN04vCefdkzzvhuvWxqMw4jCm3@MNp4UmV9/L7l@nPfT4QqW@XZIBW6CJo03jmrsBBLuA6CmTdfgLdXiVylumucKdsSnHe7wSk1r2H9/hiJG4ko414VDYl0oxyJrXD9e9tUc2nmI3YCBWzpFIN@hDAG@iCefzXCFxiadnjLdBYGSiRcBPQ5zBUSvXheCu0OVST9ZDBTycFtbptxU/FxWcXZW4C4sBvoM9zZnZ8XDbFIgbW9NSv3VJMV7iamUfJrPLYwfCJizmczqXbhnS@FHV/@@uHkfMis/vV4fxvcTlO7Ypel94Nz9Zwk/fMIAt5COb5X3G8xMRFB15vQpU2WnziicP8gLnxeCzKBN2UYHrz2aTjXGRjN5m4@d90hh7ARyowyhJhwUlLeaG9S/vj05FMh3prf06enxxoZAuEfw@hfB4bqQcZSQFx4TnfYzBwObwPixpJ6Dx8foNNKtZ@bo0Bzf0MoLg4G0zBYuQEscMuLbahP@FAMlQrOKGl6ThpN6hdlZPVUvhEu4t39QZitk7Kw1NQUpD@RYSOQsWfZtGSDRS9MR2GvQUbzP3Dx8IQ8JHyWQiQ7lKUSb2J15I4qAslwhO/1i26cQqfpspbfchmGjpY6ETDcMP4SINPlaPtyLzZtQTxWm4kPm3L6tQKyErGoyRQU/nMdFTNMoeG2if6ifktBOvdggeculqkZSz6WyGxKVzk54iV5lo5pYaRRlBn2uYffc4eCyed52Ohct1mX9N/VRY/zuLWOZNYZHfNMPuVlHPVvE060KQzMgObaRIoYVGXxEJirPZMY0ss2H68lsMvwuLKHFQfjQWDmPJyBmuJSt9HwuxJNyXrFXyVaLdjFV6FXsagHP6nnxohfX4wp6PITOE0QLX5CveFXsSn8Rnm017Qs2GNbHMEoKzn4wOvuB/TvOcIk92zRfTtuMpQe4WQ3PkGi2eakEF0YjZ0qo/0gP6BCPjqe9aboYZ1uaFuQAqJ8AZdUd0e84Jj1IacO@51CISEhFFmLvrffSA//UUYomDACkYlX97GwSngmMgus@3HfMd0OrOtfGdDzqGAuhqGBMknbymSzjEUDMqDh6ValKrmYajQ5mAq8GfE/R2OYmvzP8GoJpkg53ahgDOviQqqIT1zfg0afFBEyCFHOXjm9IUHx819HBfWgKyqPzLrTRXSJFEENwGze7ouNIFH8TCMAJ/4CrVJqYwRSKFeiJ/KgfzR2gXbjpcT2uIuApSF4pD7CwiJunV5wgpx3fRCNMVpAJ/B9cIjk5reAjSqDq9HajGAF8jIMTSWgZWry5SEuqUgoq4aM7iaaEoql@NB84RIoHd1IDJ7Jg9PPUhOYzZjtmtwuZ5rR4MCEHOuk4rkg/HqTvVjDNapB5Hq7eCFenwjUezjM1gdKg/54A5cNAcuRqAnfN5AlY4kZaRUa6iQY13dBA45jAFm6DdTXPqVkT4FJQlZwrg4DNqQA1FPJqTu3zkKWpOAGDB@EVHi74Oy1qPsjlFOzj6fTxKYkKMmlvrNhKMsOlmm11H/HOKQhBNpMZXkLPo2N9E9vxRimOTApxAgoaTuNTsy0VJ1jiui9xqM3Ipc3HsiaUiUfKbDb4ocMbDWtOGwlRidKME@FGdL4Q0qHgpRAKwomMxvyWW/Ijj0XkcQgtQi35yfJDizcaOBRttokX8Rjje/zxG/t05ny4yPzABzznI154fhh5mkAkdJfk@WSaliZ47IN7ikLd0otM0h7PYpwvJJ6FJnmDNE1@ZLqFs9xLgZwICwpfUtygexAiKD0B0H32XVSFGHgt/SK5In1ugArd75ojtoWjCINOU0lT59HRLqqLBo3QNCUMz/v9Li4qkmJ3SSeehW2OdAZXUyYYQ8tomrSPG3c4fAJd4vw4RNLYIWK@xP0fkwB32G7zG@cZ2jEC0YoTKpanSVv2mM9XQJtZTfNT4SYbunxRFAbz7XAmeM3x1oOUpuvaNQl0MRe0HIkXtcXbt5gux2MhaFILurS8JH1naDXOdz7H5dp1PbWqh0h2IVZ7U9rq2uSgFBDJD0inQF3N6GuSFFr6bfClXxURJtgBdvQvgDfNC7wWV9qCHoMAXVBOXXNwYTY1STo2gzVexIusjAuPeGzaGQ4afO4GdCu8ThdP@7oJvtoFHIZP7J/5anCDlsISEq5JTRaToaovrCYS0D9Q0nJw8ZfWI/BUP6cHRuqZHhBlJcams0RLyyIvpLv0cJ4JqIFmSUJLDwEZbMezGlAzNFEldQEVX@WYJMYv/w7lBNJrdA085KvNywCefplQwM@Av1J0Wx4ksSb@SXlgomD@Errh10wSpJ9DbQWauzmwQPpOCEy1QtFCeYcKPn2yf8JODvdOX24dlxm4j44PX@zvlnfZ9te0hI3r4GS7lT05PADpEiyW80XxQ/CQt04gpkwB0tazr1n5q6Pj8skJOzxm@0@PDvYBG6A/3np2ul8@SbD9ZzsHz3dpcR0wsGeHp@xg/@n@KYCdHiYoVT@aNInHDvfY0/LxzhN43dreP9g//ZpS3Ns/fYaJ4aL9FjvaOj7d33l@sHXMjp4fHx2elBkWTNrdP9k52Np/Wt7VIH1Ik5VflJ@dspMnWwcHMwU9fPmsfMxoD0ColNtlyOXWNgxVMSUq5@7@cXnnFAs0ce0A8SCDBwl2clTe2UdH@asyFGfr@OuEQHpS/s5zAIJAtrv1dOtzKJyk3EEVqJed58flp5hpoMTJ8@2T0/3T56dl9vnh4S7R@qR8/GJ/p3xSYNLB4QkR7PlJOcHwRiJKGnAAtSAc3NvPT/aJbvvPTqHPeH6E2xliUMkvgTCQyy2IuksExl0OWFog0uHx14gV6UAVkGAvn5TB/xhpStTaQirghomd0zAYJAhEPA0Xkz0rf36w/3n52U4Zgw8Rzcv9k3IMKmz/BAH2cb/F18A6kOhzKjXWE@SLO4FZJZ9zE1SdbH@Pbe2@2MecC2jggJN9wS1Etp0ngubQlpNSaLLEcnBuwOiFJ1BaN70uTDTAeHPmZf5cTGDgaOdwtwwaH7efJU/80cBw7v9r79m22zaSfDa/og3aIiDxrrspKJbseOJsPJmNPbmspFAgCVJIKBJDgBZpR3vO7sP@wH7Afso@7KfMh@zWrRsNiLKUyyaZOZNzYoFAX6qrq6urqquqC4mP7G@w0ZiP8DOXYGYQ9uajbjQZTjFU1FRj@8ZlMqriVQ0eaOfqtPSB2zrEjEIVyuVu98ujLui5r7tdr3qfmjkw7qohRu4PlfJkjJiXHRVvtO88ecJoP8gh6nBNjjHJDQ@PF7AkI3@NHduCy9BTjcYglGoYg48NawtRwociF3hQApyRQhnx8oKsSzJA0O9IqIEqurr5er@LVlD0e6RC0wT@mfyQ/eC9wXoBzJmtWo0G6rAERvQu1N1wJ5TZgP6RxALRkLqsJ2H4/cht2t2hyl8fTacD1/N0HSqbgho4cr07qvfCUaF6rVifgKVDZUn8nmi1myQYc7osKFMyL/UZjczFf7op/fE0NJy6AW2i1BWZosU26a5xdfQ3qirJUIHBEzTJKPK9Ovr65VeozDXbW53C@0/Me15b6A2I@WNhvzuhemf055MzLgALjFJqAEoiSXTRaFh1tDeJKXwFBS@wEGXGp636IqRtHVACcuw8GNt94mY8ixY29MCG//DF0avjP794AZwTod3a297d6ZRMkqyvq/z3G@yH8ppSjrAYtnEQ0@iTtUqegdxDK8XKhJ2RPxFwo4EFMde4njR6iekajFdG3k8J@RgON8GbPCbogOeEiAdHUR6NhyVNrytXphCAmxuqh6O5DBYk4QcgKhENiKvKeEmztsB/sG2z/PUSNwMSAhISo2yyQLmgXBDfc15oR1DSbSjNDhapO5qOOemawQFZusg7FmNn6ZfQtjWLCTsq4nqlaaeaAMTDIhRKe01MeGX/idKFiJ2Xcn3Bm6@F3uDxG0lHR8npgiQ9Sl8DGl@YmmiOzmzOMugTafns0IcpWlszPR0oNOZ7AhStPbEam/we1mogUM7QZdBXhYY7Jh1IsUvyb31a8dR7plTMwYHtdIRi5TdQ7qrhSCsdnQZEfuvkEorbMrlKGGtXpo@SLvKNSUeh0ZlD08/CB7X/G@JkRfsHoHBC6xm2rJR998Iktcq4Au2VkBJd6fME6xAjw6b96pusmWt7Yi7MwOSQZsHRM4ACmZ2lfvENJSkcuisQgESOdg17/RqHs4sANKenjifV8Thk0r@MXSV7hd4qbrR7ViWZq6oPUPCHpzw2NFndfQYV1VP2kUtF4QIu1luqx4nDbWy0PJ27o7FORg@zyok0L9gRtUhOTVlaevFLmiRrlxmYbEcgil7feiK3rqwsljmGL6daXsfObmkPWNAGfR4ioCvHjR747Iqbz5bIuc/fUAY7TIeNOjNuRZJurkdOl@MQ23k8IMsIXjGaXuF2MebWKc1e1ppyH5NTCHaSeRhmOQKR@Xp1wDptslcGejJTIr0a6P884YzyIZu4dIk6J/MQCO3Q@Lp6FSwR5vH9xu1knW8gWg/z/b@cUOrBfso7ZTxNSHOHXlDTf5xkGNFuOLAPZVgS/0tH02h0VYsW8If6qsnIdRJH0BkoweQqof/6VoWA8kvmT0iVczoxRqQnvJH5j7X4gk@8ds3TN/gkdmYfBgXAwRs8ThUxCEFGuQmP8G6uNoIPc8N9FYWzgW2Wg910EMRoASLxezqhbVdbrySDXD9Ik3AJUmi/ES0a1EbX/XR6Mek@m46DUTSNAtAVMIX2ghcgPi7pEfN/jmbTq4SuXKEPA6vQYJk9cwYTzuiFv83RWMfK8pSkYezaJ@LpbHl0wYkIyHiLbmbK8ExKohoX022ZOlvbWaVSPsKRPL5aXufWuputVZX58BgbkGV1WDis5yjFlEJfrPDGzo0CvQ8VsGDsqZoKvFt8wnIQ7wOK6CQgB7EG5sYJuD0I1A5uhfhksKgOKJ3dDFP5hM9DvLQkcel1NcCbIYHTf4SH0k9Ua69pVWVD/gJT2uHD8nZ0t3d/Y@gBgJ8BfmtzFbWsIgRK6DvU@XwSlpklLyXAQg5o6FZZRU0AlOTpLBqBYjvONdpdFFvNf17ehg1yMoGtWTK23aBKXJEuCN94QZfbBZbTXXrqhx9URVU8ygyBO@JR6jZvJ9jwLg9NWvx4jsjGG2RMz6Rl1wL6NlT1AUt4LWDBgdMGmbPw3r1i2u37zloBgf4qpybrhgDX0fslxTiIzIMnK9MZMGOngD3xNqgk6TSu3BN7t/KOlUm@VuG673l3upoysfmLjfb6gFDrL/Fx2SkV4SkQTR5j5NQENIQqFD0bMi8iceF3cb353eUdeLgNZ5mLjtlUzHwPeO3jpvgWfUb1RmOWFMGO@S475v1JFwbevZ2DSJss4neJY3SRZXSX/Gg1VUCTwdL9MUTUJ7AX8DEAzGG/A8CdPT@3IrXoj6WzZ@pPuXyJiE9M9Y1hgcCX4iGe/2MiMj4iMUyKs5qHTzCxK50mtWo9zFeLH7hBDFYJa5kthK2I2WQV6IjyyQ/dLjqstJATwdOhfchu0sQbhFEedzEwyKF7d1lrnXW4pYVpCWRZKvWhlnREM/w86S6olRuogCW@AhVmRDd408X9R/VzxwLloAWuTZ/Fl7RZxcF4agOggX/sT90FysBZV1Izt6LyC6FLrAHWAqgho3HI2hNKf9GMKR4P2GUZgWjPr138syE1MAH0TtNgG6ssBkss4gm6ebV5qnbIVTKC4t@IflmKLOqSugQNhAwx1Pdb0AJmyCTo0TBNyV1syssBKnMEFf0WLkt4SQk2M5fCFd8RqVJga9sq0VxVYt9uo7ayERAsVpfJAAGZZXWRrBXY6FbCYpXYXT2erAQIxJr2GeMwFTIreRyamWMEwiNBazjKSUtVm0LB9HFr28t9NPRNX/eb1tdm8Svgx0B4UmsVv@41c19z3bbb@aq5moAPz@419xFQ4dkAG67w8/6j4Ac7e7ZxS7SUjJyUIa7AE1SlrlBvq3@XqAMK@9Uyhm7Pjj3W6leXL@XI5ff@cC5vJZniOz9/sNo3UgMiyeUp8ZmOpnBZHySB1cGdHkeFiq5O5WYi4LVKOx2qL9@8eJHLK9pbaleXy3C23Ww2kYZ7dhp17cWL9oto2siXbgzn43Ejvvp09mWvQawfb9weJ9MnWoEOYUZgTST16WzEVwkgDFAUS9ckUhJV/flwaOfsx0MynDuYNS4p4faK9p/IuF18@YYMPNSk7K/nOEAc37kyi@8qYDlTWtEnIVAbnVLfOvoAB9CDL4boCWwOS6gx5Mvanwa2Lc8/fI8bCF6FQZNFiXC995mDrPNJOB5Pq@qr6Ww8wFD0B9fFCi9e2BWaXAQPuSh8dJ5QwtOqCt9GYytwFYvYpI7N6X1JX0ygM4xjlvUvwtHHi9h1Tr51YFeBIW/gMDcw03FVOSPHk7Tj92iW6RDAvlfpyyB2@4SnYmHY6WUBZ08A0WarulL1yRXx6IoRwdndpRGpq8GtUzYAGLpHooDOik7TSyO5pbhBrnO6aA0Rh01uQ2DCpB73q4GxTL8dV3ybDof3Y4qUUJ4n9ldniGSRphUoyw/wifmY/6kGy/pFIWMFyzd47cNNvoMVulihVHrc9/9y5R4dHalH8caGOjo6hodaTR0dH6nn@OL4WD2H38f4e81vb293mOc@997Dy2P98lodQxtk4NzoX8yew0/45mNgEvoL4xQ/aviPqp1HXf/gsJM0To6OMW4cnv76b//x13//z8aR/Pgv/HFMP06@NYXq9XrjUf/9o7XrDv4@eX5WedQ7eRSfVUYdpDJk93@eJcE4sBwY6/3SHUE6g3HUuy1wx3hwRAl5C6LHngv/@D5oYD/8wE@nafY4yx4xLWdWPRjHFwFVV9TCoV85qqytwdOBX/mXCtlO5H1g3r@D98pDXk5x@4RavHpGHb1@9vKlnfkauT5J78MQ07Tg3YhybBJNkggGdV7Wd87VTlS9rs5q6tyAh64GXS6YB5HVTAbmXwVIPTryC6HzU1Eb8GCUTN9skedzkstkRPKdNp3z/VuBaCqPB0/4UIfa2ACGh@U77C4toZc4fAAXT2H82klrZ/usVi6XS@ZOrm6f2Bz1FlNf5o4mfYxLZzAcCRTDkoGx8x33iAtoEJFRLtONTWt9vlnMnaBqTRoTK9zliiXPo72JBlIybI4t3BzPjzIWKnx0C5ZK5hQIgLLB8r5HSgAARXgdEONSfLFuEof9aLg0x@54KULWO@yVGLW1roY3graUM@s5Mq6Hw6xBQAhKAZQuBhstNsjIm0LZiLgdj1H/BnHjJlGdS/5ptUUTbJxS4ul4ORpDZy658yRXwJ0A855M1niio7mwB67ZC4d4qTuvaJ6wzJ0U4e6FaIqY9EHBHOAVRWNMC8UCHx9BUkJEWA8o4cgVZUOMRnDHE3ZimQ7hETZ8DOTi69iIDDdwSxWCQqUWlWN9xZnwgfXY81TMJRGr8Ds7ACbyIBMk6cNy11ruKDD2pCa@PRBKi/F2OVSkJT2lJyvJobViDmBBqrzEAzI8HAOkYMk6XWcFrGGpzseTczN@PlJL8EY8Oj/jC@eomzafkQPHMt3oiG3qjt3RHTau0uVXkyAV9MbTJIl6gKx0qaeJsvCx//oMWj2tlLgzoRY8qEME46v12Kwoe3yalMJFTCHiDO8DNO1ONBXkCuKxIp6J8dlwOXdSPJlOasRye2Ea9dmJj3t/qHlxjMe05L1PgN3eESgPfFCpJ5h6ONUJbuSMkqY6a4fwhP7yuP4vjOgdEM7EzCssWmIXACBDHGZ2TjMkZS0aSqAG8kgRGMkFWTD4IEeY43AUpbk6VUkCwJ7PPIprjXpc5OcIsI3dAmbRV59WZc/aZ84F39o9ABmv/gaMds@T@NtVtKcHg7sa331oavKQKKRr7yZ9GH6kwbGhhhUM6MPlW83PEG2uuNdRHjPMJjnIk6rKZuGDPVDjAiLzi3WKMaEGhFsUcVI7AWy0C9gAdlpYBhkXbuaatwgYidveyYlHFdDL08UiwQ3mrelFQ4pEcF0yUSXv/7/7zU1lb4YhsrD4oBTSAezRmZuDSeVQbHLlCrwKtaAu@dmANc7mmBSN3SdkR8EsKhEvUqtTA0ehKz10meEaSUoxpeiAnycVey4LVfV4s9pn@dq1CkcVvdexRa4l6cSehBzJ1we8mbd2tnW7HDRER2/061pHN0lwkPGZ0LMjKKftNRgietALg675MZNzvYo0tA6vubwes0gWIFzmGqe26IhGytmeKCuQxL4KR/N0@jL95WV6Sm8sZ33mJd34CXJBAGKwiAiB15AneEQPWO@XUguQD0TACNiHKkhCeC6VWPIQDdN5lYyOpwu3WT11Tp1qa2ffc0hPNnJYuZ@AZlTuh5ywC28NFN2TEgOSXfttyCx81osGg3Ci04FCVenNfOpKsydozn9v2F3Cl6w6xMRDx@LlSQ0mkV4Iruk5ngWjy4Ae/zh9MwuWL2ETop@fT3g@X2N7X8BmhNcC0ZcveI0eDUDUcK5RT85o4l5DpJClACSffkqiASeDs8SFFQgIbyCA@zTjT/KDtdBgj59tF0Z6pn0TJvWcJZSEHXnP@eDkvMR3zl7ipahdfge06VqX0sojfSrclCwyAn7QPmbWW67Bov4YT3rCSe4cQmevFcLjm4u5VlWNgUCbWuX68FCm7JN7bqBPzkWxSfsX3cv5OI1kZDeGpceFlYrX75I6qW9MvuUKXjIZFnFnjQPbPYlglWa6DDGqDAuihOlWLP1Ro5vGT2bHTGgQVYUzT7S3iD6a150PzA1L94da1cDEENaBjVZOcZwlS92A2p1Sts8qM@qHOeUD4QCkIBjrMd19TKz52p5jnGFMXUHMxEzur6Gz/y0rufyGThsyLGm9FKNfQWRgHpbp@uTZXlVNOcS2tFqgFL78enoZimYr6oSlvFoXl3E@x99cYb1Dc8tJfxaqtOewLbs8zC20nHCoXTYtdBohhnZmexZorLYwYksSxHJiic1nPEtL1xwYvZJtsFICJRnmopCtJSYz0hXsDZq4sXlWjRhx45OnpTcjAVFRoKmBZqqyu2Ubm1x6jVa9bAfTsOZlSltkV9kGmsmsK5RwQwZ3Iiq8iajWT0MUw7UKT/zlF0NTHgF5LF2XSqvI17AOcc2y17qJYrnBlwhxD40gXGhjhaDbG2PeugywYnN4abxI9vtaGF5XRyNgi3lZmD2sg@wdaz2sQCaFqGVjiGOv@PkM87qWQboqwf@YYxe41CUadHIWEBBZGyVTiGKUEBuEb2ONkKh51Sh7JfEZapT5pprWbsujTu7REwaB/gzxntkgHsUMbwRg4YZCIse66koQ2927H@11t5ilc@NbaZIGjpwZpZk9r8cxOpPfZaVulCWbgqugeeWpn2igJltJm/cgtPM0yqUHAAJLGpjWDTqj2hti4E1CGIZJCsnm3MwNi/VDbej@Pdm/NY61r4JQgBEQmlo6QPmMbiHmCRYJgYIpaYFWHicVQLUJ5VjZSyaqkbhIqM1Rst7BW7JVrzQImVmhXTpR2SWes9SyKq60mmoLkSqvrKZczHKJ1gw6Ogr7aAg3VqrEs@zBYnZoQNtyKTSAxcF6pskcu7KHs7amBDYyWRdkjJWKfg5RDEcOGacTZs5F0gUmhC8J8bKlwDIxUl@80v7ABaREtjrXVgsiyF4zOSSz0DQyvM8nBvOrsUNVP4QfCoaYFoJcCCfEUU36kQya0o9FaBGfdxApGfT@dqj0R83EfUlVro6@jRZ5L95t8V5s7z3LpIHWBtx98G/U51hTCm7M9h@1bgcAP@D9l8wU8A8TKMUrpCaQHbh9knpy3fWDTK@rJ2mXb@427Bf1OHG5GwxgOwZmS5FNVdATU/JBUhaetYMtBbn/qA1TK@ncvbBCUDERlKJmJrUzvUyRYmapvzoynjA1lFDiB9AcuRdRNCEeXU37HJsOGxR@H1JkOum1LVaLUCHiiif4U0L8Hgw5U95QVjKPQK13pVsZg8BDg2AZ63gWpPcSsbIjOXbYN5fXF@kwqZfUyx8vkt1HLlu/t1xWXieb9nomnq2XY5AtNn9iG7@unJYZaKEdx0Du4EIlAz6pHIBimKAxehhnxnzhWvaR208X@/4hvvxeN4b13734sm7Q388LMeuZENNfKcRkBaRWHw1vVM@UJ/YAy3ZCGvK6iD3c3zTfH6wb3d90ZX98GbjKyknlKXWLr1d0m15NpYYhVOmQ7I8rO0Jey2v63JG1fa7cmwua5zvbhjf/sQ3/fW/DDYMLTHh5x05jTf0/5v7vYe4xheJ4r7nX7P5i577mnWMTllM4b1XKeahahx/tni6eN08X@1uf/6Wclg/bja9m8Dct/6W8s1fmR3iAX5v619vyYfkAi@1cl5cN3/fhUVo5egGtHH5q2sRSywP453Bbt7uzLB/WfKr@Q/lwBx5a7TZAcrr4eP90sdfE/53O70n8sE9XjPBxW6sx5VWRDYHPAsVFntTyaZI1@czaHV4iCWh1PG8gxZ0fGq0RwOg8s2jvNUVWAQLi/A9vQ7kC6jLEq7uMeYpymKSUR4MjLnT@B/HV40qwAkwXHvyhLmi3F9Eryzmh002glJABrc4f13fw6Ppc0lAYAEziCRIz2ZUb1AuXOsYUW/j3sPmRYxJTPHEkb4Vje/zL2absinuyK/5vWcXL9GI6aa9IrF5Wz2C60lB9lzAsySSK4zBliX8UTkLYktGYHk1R0MGb3vp4L944@p7d/57oxlWfGup@l3Q5NocbqsdL5Tx6CisruiSt6B2sSv2M52M7W/oXMG68MwzjZHR0zShKL@Y9yon/ZrZ8mX5OmSgamFc75awUDZDleo3LAB0HKJN8AiQGJYAdzOaTBt0tBgIbxspg@vfL4HsADe8zhaENulAMjf3fu3R5aBLGFOKyGA4duqknHA9eh3EwCzhrGnrNz4NR@BITw8BkJBcOKk9l9UcKrknt7LhGWSKMgxwuVzLVOIMV8f6kosM/CbVKYbgx3RjjYJy6MCHi3U6doiaglsOhBXRL9XA6TbPyHDVuKtDPfA3KCQaTxKEheDiYjQi4OY5/QwOxoZS8IDiyn9Jp9oI6ImhmKsKbHHBU4WR@SbRjblY9aT05k7xpfsu64Zo8XveeyK3mjoMIxWkSY3NrD7/M2feSziVLkjrAjAMEa4YECvKEzOm08BI0hSSZ9r6jvD/IlWBBIv3V9TdZ9uRGD49o7J6Eo4B4xVUvSqnAIEqoANZsjN6B7M4oquZItTcfJXVeCxRYESXJPNze3dsigGjH10UH036uaLsBLc@C2bJBwF2kl2Mziv30Qo3Dt@FYvFcIbMooy4uS6Awv1QrmY3Jr2fGIdACVuZECFtz9Kr97/vGLz47efPy8CmLKNhZPKCzJlHUt5PLnDfo@HGOmBiYjrMLLt97b2WIid5Nq5Sla5Bj0pzbaN2yAdQNJUsc9IIrdik/VxM@CG1Yxqu2TUdUch19NZ9@bxMW43BCUOd124Gjk6pVfLmNIV4J9lZEEc4kNoA4OTEduz8bAeG4UupVXAAaEu3VToMgx8k@kXOfgYa1m1tQTeqoBY63VDtnI4jwbR6B4Vr6YT3LctkJrJ1AVYHJ4/M@s7WGF@ELd6agLH/X4Tt9vdkzc3lt37r03tyIPEQqXEfdmerzU8@fOJTLNAYR45OWsQyb/578rXuc6S6IzdlMPs/@rd75OXlxnpv4xX5fqVpI@TFYK1d7V03CRPuNsk37aMRV608FSrr1/Blr1wH1n9xG73nvYqzc2@r6/6b2HLmcxZqGMgRmGb6BFr4Pvhrl3JkSscXo6wTuQ1zF07@tXn30CU45@YmGSnnx7tv6oUa1UPK@DQwh8iu97/vmrP6GVf@bVydr/Yja9FLzMAtNJHWb7MjlpnhH0VQeH1sBVCJxzFKYy@uR4@SYY/RGkJbcSAArQLYkC42BSooNA4ss66JuEMhfeD2LjyHfyk@t470c@lbqYhcMO2yquE/@tO/I6Kfy5sLvYhi78dptaT6GSj15NBaxHE9itP3nz6jO/chAobNVfsSoqGz1DHEAoRDAuvjrCG5FypANchagq5Wg9Ihj4b6PiHObHctAIDiud6@tb4fmMc7qC8FPJCHjgzqtCcTP/5pR2ZhkVLOPQxxe8tf3h4zdOFepiChZ8OcHtbUlMi4NYfd0HkxtyCtoCl6@xjO9vra3RO6wyT3y/3Wx6mBHlGlpL8ApzaJYX1qxzPQv8gWsQGcTRigt72vV2gwNZkkZrp93c3v1oOoMtwsc70dcSYCE@ai1vo3S5BrJh6OvLf9ZATobd1H@4tb73eXT8z1/vv9557vZ7n7acqvNdQm77s9gGYBZc1VksAh47k3yvBARGLvaDRhx8P21sDZp9kDxbu4Nwdzvca27u9bfDzf3e/v5@f7i11xvs7wa72/1eA/ONU5X6ZTQBKclh8sduh/fr9jbBbK/d3B8OW62d3cH2/nC/3dzc3OrtbQ@aW1vDvVawubkzaO/19nsfltoyeErAYDXfxb2jyIEf3y7clW7wdqnt/R8)

This answer is supposed to be tested in cipple, Kipple interpreter written in C. Interpreter should be called with `< nul`. This answer doesn't work in reference interpreter written in Java.

Kipple has `#` line comments and multiline strings delimited by double quotes. In cipple invalid instructions are ignored.

Previous polyglot contains several harmless instructions except for `t>o` in `<script>onload=...`, which pushes `0` to `O` stack. Contents of `O` stack is printed
at the end of a program. It is fixed by adding a space before `onload`.

Main code is inside 2L on line 94: `"269">o`.

`<` fixes Flaks. TapeBagel (`%++ ...`) was moved to fix Cardinal.

Answer (score 3):

## 270. [REBOL 3](http://www.rebol.com/rebol3), 12530 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
# 
#  
#
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 #ata",_"[];=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers951 6 4>8370::$/  \0Vngt=BFloatk:pext se>ExPrs min94 Cr~-<u Uint 22FACw;re-  82:t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIdPMDvM172U0Oye6@94JodAEoENUEqtBVBRJoNjtmxhuzGkvhlcezitForTuSLa@0doRlh72Sw1I4Qnp1KPykH9Dyy4ZiQ/MPZs85mVUogADJHo0iFiRQWZknT2aePHny5NfJhuF1fvGLGH7YodMdnXUdn/mm57OWa12Yrsa2RuyxYXm57LIkIdSmezbombbvFaQY0xmzzUu2ZzetFvgx3zk3beud6UJYlrG@65y5Ro/5HcOHFwtisR2z@7733mdNp9cz7JYHkMuMHRoQ2B40z5nR8HzXaPqWY0PQCmPP7a7Ra7QMBhCm23dNn9DnGKBonlOcyZBVxp46rmdi8k3T8xz0XGNsw@z1/VEZXvIAYbiWs7/57POpyOuMfW5AzvpdcziVFz3DXlqm25qKoevsxcnu7rRvln2pOjbbvZk/fZk9dz2ja0zjX2GbA9/Z86f9c2zzzLQNltXWtex04Crbco0bUdaYaxqtttU1NctuMpV1zG7fdBn6sLbjQpX5ZjefyWfqm@OYWhPj5seBU2hLwYcZ7pkHgc6FCU4TaqJvmS3Wdp0eM2zvElLS1zNjeES7PskOTcggMBp740Hslsk82@r3TZ8HQnFNl4IhZda17HOJc9@h67QGTcs@AzgT6Nof@FQmT2pCtDLrCx7W0MFiRAUOBlk4dnpmtC48YF7Itdc3m1bbanLimEPftD0or6cxC@ru0up2WcvsQoQx9maKeQ4beBGvRtfoaE1NQuJiKqx33mUWa/b7jAdBMSBLu5k8M3vOG4u9g/Bux2PDfo95Vg@C/abTbpsme2f2OxCd9VpSy5EYfJr9qZKFb4smwNgmlG778Gugm4/ktNuQtRZrROAgH5RnKrFhO0A@l9lGj3NDsz@i0gOaMEbbcTT0bzmmZ8d9dum456xhNg0sNibmmWdtY9CFFK02VgfwgeWxngNPqESbQbYgso@0QNyYmDSzIJhMUL1mHxomVq@D7AJ1HdTypWsAf7ieqEff6gF3WH7cY6bhWSixIIpn2i3ijH4oyxwobbTS2YUFDQ9IMXAJt2e6xPqEl2EpAKUR8qpy6Vo@cASWYpMdmobLTlzTTHA@Nb2m0UcujSYJiTmYgo8F0YgxNzbilYPdODAoj6EZfWBId/nkO19IBtNKbLFehG9JlotS5dkOu1o8RTeXmcDEfVcxEqz0gXnp01MTvkO9kT5zryXAKgFVuizt9P20ofYhg6oPGUwb6ESXepHV@t1Iwmxjqg4izYZDtaA2QAiwFykqWXPguijdx0Q1zqHQXcc@A3pCYd2Bzat8NQNVAPzX8lLMvDCRB3gdOZdE4ZMOcAj8A2hEsvAOhwgKXQ40RUHRIF3P6Q4IDmJ6PrZHoApERYx7bfaCtQ2ri1EgHFHxXLumB8yJcQZ2C2u@Z9lmS2NBNkjquNAWLyA5A5CSB7SGXkS2UKYAGCrCoaJi0Mff/J3W2Rng2Ww2Hbcl2PUFMHuTukaDMgudG0OGdWyjS9kCuBSmzqNDAhdG12qRlDPskUiCMkGpXjqDbotRQ720oMl1DBC2JgiIpm9yJncGPuQxxXrGOZeIFudcKHjPaEDFUgKUNhVbZY@3oZaa0MyJZ9TewG/nmdqvsLiXfqU8KiiPFk5NyFxCSywtptNnRWA4bYm84C1@G@e82JzoKjzf8ByrJfVHfsexs0xtMrlZcvqmrcQncMRTcbcRT2goqZVE0So1tbZlt5T4BvBiGRKOJ4rNUrNqFWrFqejRJAHNJaLB5moqzYSMooYaxUW6B8qFBpLshSpckTDHqyPJMViLeCNhpv0uuEeMVBfkSwcZBOSQ5nVNs69kND2BYgLhZpYbA2aVdAqHKHDBqiXjsXgyWnTCACWdKCg21hPLQbHV7XdQ3wCi2F4fZK6LvNs0gHs87NR8UOlSrEF8TT0hSBaSiZdmHKR2AwRpwEfUJHmTw/gqCkqBYdyEJluy2Yo0ZBAC0JZ974Y07jqoHVCesOcB0WFjosYZVA1E5gXZ5AXhKZHPZJHObRAoiK1hsrzasKARYHMDmS54PlI2AF/OchjAxhtJRPb0jBH2alw1GDcY7NMM1gPx4I5Y00SZA8LH5B0KJjKg9ueB3sucNsuo2Vxuso3daGK@m95UvwEh/S59a0vCwkcbEwoa1gY1u2vYZwPjDOSFY0MUo9k0@74QVFASzwdRNN3fkKcqOk/N60iLj6fTpk4kUI/GaaCQ57UnukIDpYtQ21XQyVD142MB1rJcEEvQk0@lDgAXU4nLrxFkIgOv5TlZCDQAYDJzaDYHPkg1YODLjtXsAM9i7mwuF3knNJ08eEVTB8mutsOkMTN6@WFW0tKhF2ZjLgoVa/QmHuhcEVV5woMqP@pxO2bD681A7IRZhI4g4qulDQ147w6cPcd2ZiAFQoZoEWQyhNcDaGLHqBRDxxWoXdRYQ005rCKoM5Aa0PKB/zq@3/cK0E9YfmfQ0IBT0ifuaM8/sJFZ0r47snyHuxtdpwFi2YP2mQ5SSDcHDWs4VSDyC@vwjSddgALW9lgJeu63A@A6Jd72QGCS/zYCR4JkEtyEgv/KAEhAGhBKaXskindBqByP7KYiTzClnGIytl05AQ6MGJLmC1TeJrP5Brymc4lg0cxoaYRKe26THGpEJ0X0CE7Zkh5MFO2eeZQeyDL8tI2uZ8LTHnS7@DqwuZRTuK6QYFfSgwcg2hRKzur1u1bT8us8lD18KHQKtgBjPFSb2qgzJSDOAzGY1kCgAIzofji05jvHpOwqCSjIg@uJhE3XdVyert9xnUtGHggmRYm67fRQurOXpHChBg3DWsvG4b3oS6krNWaqEGGfSvpyPK69cSxbuYovLCzEC/Ey9JgLC4/AtYGuR@hKgusRuVRyIZyGLoqRIheGVikG@tXi19UA8zBRw@YwxN7@ndVXjGqhsFxLGVVdPLP4TACdoccAaBUfgCeeKJXQmUjI5UsoqNZoT5Z@G3u946Zr9QURvjAuDP4uqLBMZICKc1wcGBRRebmdJr2SC9oFDAaaHcWNn1Yzp7XTq9NW8vQ6nsLYiaJRakChID2lp525zgDUkER1paDqtUSiugzKR6MUz8SXFCWvwjAORiKJz/KJpMGprcRN6A2V09M4EFXQp9rsuIRvmMomEiGpIB@o8ICurcS1qzyk30jUEsk4xE3EUzB0K8XjQJkmEsGjQmNbmiDQwdGXnDDbyaREzRtGpfi90Z2CHw56J6MfDt69Q9nFcTRCDusODK7l9QVAes8OYDUMnBq0BkGNNkM5OpHG506bj4q28aeyvyuZQ6qtzw92K0clSqZjeOegU6hnCJsGXRmo4rY0kAbdQcuUZsGA2ABXc5wTnDvAxM@aTaY6jMDUJs9EpLtosjnYQNaQ4ukwtdubLILXgfxuT5SBkJA/xbxNf2kGWeLgM/MUJrkLEnv7eH9iiqx3DvoEa3pdVL5VlxcAXtNL3LNFj3CMUWB7NEazQcEE3gL9shXOBdiOraIsDIZzTjQhPiECEOSH2hZqEtYEDCJuW0MYEsdwPkWo/qixova/7dgwODW1lyQNZQaCHGerTG2m/n/IFSmt6Y1bJ2j64Ox3jSbI@0l0pzI7BYQggdLp2SGJ4g3E04MDGsffVUZQpZqGjfRrWTROHVheB8kLYwnsBdw2UBUHqTi5Q1TbY03Qcs@A0ubQ8vmoFVr4MUZ5YnhKAsdJm3ycgVyGOjJmKpi5IwXWacII3wRdGUP5dAmr2BeW69hIZK0CqEEUFbEOppDPIi@w0ebmXnZnPn1nIQeK3fDWI7SNYp0mbtOD1mU7XefMYUsAgKypaZyx92yc4YRRjm/0oUVZ74hAm2cODPUnedA0wznT1eVwvGkgZJrgtTfQC7DZhR4DzCnz8d43FVBD9FwmA/kP3jL0CQsZwTJdRvRssjGAWAXoIt9gTX5j9jsjd4KdPEfMm/g0eUgNk89kGaBCQq5EC39HUaONnPtAOw@CWoFrVtkrNCbAybvouHqi9BPaCm82UMLYlDf6BqSYQHqjwsf1i4LrND0ht8KpArXdc3wj/UIDEY0/EmrIqsVkLx1fiKdVFX9lCmLZMku3zIs0Sqkx5mHFbM7EPTTNZhpDsXNjgWMmeYLAOaQ5hY9NP1BM/gxoEMacLv9ZMomCnXIXps0zDZ38SWdgSmaz4zD5FIYY0ZLJ0EF0YKysAuVBAcRxSRhNrAhJvjOAYV3L7Fo9y9@jOfuujWMXjYS3hlJLhG6DvBkjOLRMUMj5hMO4k8F59XEfZZ9x@COQ5IQVhvgaJ6lrttJLY2xPHceFcaXHdJpTyIak74mAtOP1W5o/BAQ8VoX6dy/o558d7FTqh5snT0rpgeemu1YDZETLrPdgMNuF5jDng3nDGcIK8I5lOz0LShSgfHfePXIcnysPuHBwv08MIwY49nfq@3tbR5tHX4vMUY9u9QZdA/NYWJwCCHEcE8ytaJpOwwHdwh7MxQTKxcHWwX6A5Yvn@3ub9Z3K4cFJBM2bQdcy9GG6f342r0BfIAjTtQwn/UG3NbmiQ8PUiVkEIWxwzFVkMDZlqgq/KvrxRHFUpmEAqsjYPaoqzgIbOM/tsqyeWV9vNYx83lxtNVdW1tpGu9Vayer5XDufy@Yy8LO2um6y9wSuquaQZm7AxWdFcAIJ04DM00PXVgINB4aiTdBYRjPzFYbekrlmLmeurawb68319XUju9ZaNrL5NdNcXWuvZDLmqp5pN/J6fvnWzEWygarV@K1HM0DQ6nCygAJB@CnwmGgOPPOg612yVjabXW3m2uvL2VYus9JqrGdy@VZDXzMa62amvbKsZ/VWM6sXgrg4owpSogMVhlqlDappEKTqEJiQgs40WsW0yhgsQwuBs7iMIqYfLCPjwEEErGDAQCwi49Ss8M@hf7CEjFM0wn8V/Xu4gDzWZOk19BSAeQLEdWTNbQSe6@gZriBPrK2CqBTyc1b4/EgC85WeuUbkl7gGHSnfla6T/4Xfbk94Z8n7XMWurDv2XiZvvgI9ufYrCnsjaCZwiG@F8PGV65n4bgTNBA7x5Tg@XPGejW4qZBZoiGyVkOEK@UxcUwEzAENMa4Qpuqo@DstT2LwldZHWzOC5kULc64Sbr5bX3/DVirpYLEdu5g3kBDSxfQf0530L5@3bEy1GCkfgp5IcTCNMTiSNQ7LjZRKmXsxe35GjiLgwsOxzhwbOoaue0fQcYglR9M67N2O2YahBPxOgNzJ1M4T3X71Gm35mAGCnOz0zRwE07Sm6fuhqjfQRPXACdFYOJqdyJ5JvmO0BjILSDctG9x1g6nqeINuNhjUPFCiBmw@C5wywAjsawEg0q61oejDsxaUTkNl8HvZk74AAGwYN4ibn/9kE8f2B60Ms8fxv321BJdysoo4xorFg6Kjb5iXxR3tujYmo@EI/s2t33OsTYch1F8qmgUuuRjd0zEZNta@qHcPt4ZBLVDcwKP4AJ9zCazznfC4meM5OpMCIyJPrDMy2eqw5A5pgp5ZEeGI0yO46RovIwIfClkmRXKxsXg3mkA8KIwoP9DzzEpqxcsHGWwX8zsAf8F/cHXBXNVp9/N7WRAVkJmc0dBNUZKNhmbdUumucD1qOCpoeFRkztjoDdlx6mqxT213jnDvr6JxdfF5A1zo7A31CPOeBXXZgbEOD0vQlPe7iC88eeH21AZXlQ8OhN2oKvVtScLv8dx6IJfbPhY75VLO69HOPSg@Zi9gFVDoiNG5pUiNEs6bI3DUaIxyqdz6dyzBBUnBA5pSayWRmGbu9cO03uhVpfnzsKyn@@vrs2HwzFSfJrOFVmm@iUvkEMpVZbKu6o2Kh47J6RlfNtiLOuRI9mDoeu2aA0ryN2uwaHrCWL6rDvIDqo5/b2B17piYMu9yx6xZmH2cn2AIwbzVZiC3RqptO1/KwaXfnSdDpBbhxmridjX4iU9LWLMK2SGfyOmromi0XnKaPS7lzGO0eUo6vouI6dYRzNGce0ZrOJX7nqhYd58Lkv7M7unczc3UPiaV2iSWs5swepdW8i1NxOxD9zKbj@cx8@c3uTP/JNhBMcUQHaPfka8/qOh47pt/byHLmQjT@O5ujoxS0DFul9aCoe3Y0kak@08Qs65x6NbpnTnc1f5Y24Gdu5Q/cNvYJ4nlf6RdKL12/W3oF@pFj6@I5V@yfp93zu@qOliZcXLSPOG/pgWeJMLEoOb@AMJLAnTizC7ebyVNMLc3Hy/MqwG12Lo1R8PwlepZ51A16lv6I9G1Q/zDCeh4cvst18F8mtZXbU2vdTzzdQLt2VyEilXveNaEjo98bVcqyGf0TY@iZzP2FVbs7MAfmTFl10Hhj4v72W0Yh989URhRjUcx24owQznWGUO/E@PFeucY@HN9uFTBG14JGfqemM1Pe9UFH7@OQ@xAch@i4GfHMHvQnKndiFGcf3U65Tj9o2U5rIpMY8qkSKX@3PjWhyHsmfW8dXPHBIK5tlVYymYzQbyLz1xMvtw26lsO4byz@O5Ew@YxTHsPibIgbcc5OYzyVClVvnXsqTmreTzpl580IEPD6etq2bNMf4e@8KpklbRuO0/2UKgSh27JQfwOtFBd@7qrKG7qR2A3GxnMfHs6cNNrzZj14hyRGp0A9HHjfxg3Rqdd7VbOKS9bQSs@mXm@fB4pM5N6VCnTzNLnEt0505yueYkZF1/La2q0tkquzTsPsGvwxXF25Dd@6tnwrvlBlEXoyrW3hehhfARuvqMam5FZ/BMSyWjDI6Zg9k15vGR0YrTcDL3jMBRo6@J0RrNF647x4fQsEhY2/E6ttEVXKd2wYlvmGe2biuKaLq@LCd55wDmbVZxJ3r2ecmfxc1W3SczzVgVuH@Whw7Jw96VHgu86aEI1v/bidFaAxnZsjL3jORPh01IT6HPTunqqbavdN2qh0V0PX0jMXE@7QFe2O07E7ZofvBArf5jUP4Eifn4i7rRCQ/7NOk5F8iu5SilK263S796EsykcuLR2nPTNPFTyn1YKon4R3ZDQgQDzunAKEvp4IRJ3@vHbTMQfQZXmO7/RNld7mgXZxsoj/zpOiweLOLzsLdesMAVAkeP6y@O8cm54Zjt/v06Pe7w48@qGoKh2vm1WVu5TMfbjC8vm2I8635pnTaHasu7LUMA3fts7TwYwQf711ZNuPUMFi6g56a10LiOeONOSGUjT8GB9786pUTC7xbit0zK7jAtseuO4IKeE7DvO6zuVYPkzunwincfnqAzrm5UCsDM4IJm0Ad9YFO8huWQIRC4lzGYyUcFS4VTMDCos@d0ZpYntnpHUsL/OfeXrRVPkpU5H120@ZEhXbHmhy0IrM3IL/BP9MLEbP7KzszuDMuynu@IR9C1Qs/JlZ05tneKZ5qqJ5pUIPZNjiMY/e2W4at2/Dsw41NzBvXV3J3bq8QnB6VzUcCx51eEAdDuZOm3Wtvsd/mdrOzlQYbi4h34QazR42i/ppmW2@FoKuuzS9nuPiISJQKdSma3pNnEpHicz1Jy59bOcMJLPaZWPgAHZmEW6uWs@s/rDHU796Zp4ZuL1y38Kdlt0ZXAFYpxev70L6nYHhWd8ZOL45E9/0AvZd6J4aZ1bzyQTlA2QBRcUePP6YYHv0ukn8y47l0fmNwHHLnBMyGWdb5LM66PuzRmtT0/Xhwejbp1UiipLY@83UPRbsEQ8duGCA4cbMtGbNxDt9GjeOyHXbJLzl08yseM7kqtmbAG5L/nLQ6w888ZidOu3TiU5R987J37u0QCyqb0Eas47R9WdPY0dmZkHnEp3k2DlPC//G6jpn7Jt8hoGKBp02KuUzGG4LuutDw4cWYc9gYEr7ngulOOmhurxgb4EnzGWmWrbl3z7B4/sGjJGCJxaGdzZ4CjG9j7/a40/FoJ7Mpsj@rRoM9O2jZhcPxX/qSICLXeDCYzq0js7w3HyU70Uy5rZAGPQutnkZHa/duuhTwC7VsQe@irv8b@tTVm/tUwpsmF@NsAZTvlN5@jwR5RDa/nqXHmrCQHDgdUdj19yNB1OMZ9mgrM2XxZPQwWhixySTBke0UfOOOJt9PD1FIn/HmTXiORxB73PvIRN0IIPejtnElcc7037mPAXVDbqyPgjd3pGJWwamZMnsiBht32kaXaBP685kjgntjL5iPLg2@mYD6rc7ds3WxWYh3jF8Y47uRBOHNAIMXXfyitVtmO4bmhGMuOcNaicz9MQc0jBkPsPwVqj6zSZXuHFabqKNTK/teH3HsfkvCeEMPPSntwsb6B7o5/4r7hruX57o/WYO0iZLe3DBt5uYLX5wb15xXbPhdPkvFmGOOLAtvrnAcC3TS@9b9mBIfkwF3W32MIdv481oazjN4XWgsV1aMMYOd/fiZjW@VdibGkmBSnxheLTkP3tMM7GT@P67ijqG23Rw7Uw4PnHlLHIk7A45Hm6V5lsTGlApQxBoRnMQ2BW4I6vdXqNHP3PHJJGaPjIbeOSuQedHfWM4S4mcPDomPKcObwUiDRv@KlMOYdSTuLsjmx6yTVLc6tMPCfTLmWwSJPfMMpvvjMQdsjRsRTSXnDZoRDuzIU1uggM1p2uqfgf3WKZ9f57AeGadD1r3WOsKFlAGPRPXrCdXbuYyleN1iCOc2av0ocB1TbF1G3cJQtMP3Ch11c25LIvo4f9g64s0dMz11RU8wT8Yqmcgzu7eFwCZH7i2eNyH7Q4dz29bw4M@mnFy3HnyBYuVgyjw4M0BXUvzCgH1aQ@6fL7jLLKjq9ei8R1og20HXF0S4b6pmvaFSiaOhsFypWsEdmTm1uH05lD9jt2hl164HggBat@jZ7rvHe7tH5xofU@/ZeYQN/wNrC6u7lFWAj8oILnmT1Ef0161ey5WqPDA1biJx0zcYlW03zEapm@kjbmDHQw1/dma35OTp/vJ8cllpmx3XKdnJqLB28fHKcg7@@J4ZnA09i6weNsZzo2@V9H1xAwefG7TmuA8uTcjpXmYTkwYsgJHPeGHaO/UmppO32ydjPrmC@gSUfZ690x@dW4hnxkX1hk2JbY@l1DU2ti6troSgLyA4Tgeirp9XPKlBZosaOhNeibugD4ibeDWhS1x1IqsQoX2Q7yUOAQIfpYrDA14WmDiTJyYpA4wOLsDnkazOcC5Oii5xghQUYxkMpGQRKwnziXrof0kjOTRwd9zq19kmcCJueyAjkPwaPpAYYsG2ygBRCJR5DZEoDlAGx@YRda2AsSbnmed2ZCBIH0y/4SmYbhlKY/BMMoPsFarbPFqWMgU9GtWYnJBZrUazy9@KJHKsE@2m4549OqiUSstxlU1vhg/tQssEw/Bza5nzgY3JmAhs/gQGQ6py@26OWSULaRlkZu@gW4dzUp1DLsFVS6aCJTf5QZcuHWgE9wO/pd/2BLWtsiqXM/yjC4QBA3mQWvtOJePeLoBufp9A611IY7LDk71Y@rq9ibzLnHanhvZgsp6vnuSF6Z7hHU@eDnkk7lhLjjf4IoyHkP2OVvw3IRHSkXCYaygUDC@HfRsUChbfsfT2LFFJ4wH7vjMkLBZaPsuLhu1UmyPtUzceUsHx2mVtOs453SYDHPyl3/IDRbR8XFxrDdIngyVRVLEU@I6WQlqNp0B5DpA8s50HQGiIJGNpj/APQlkJ4/8E3iomiwpAa@rgR0hSoYbE9rePGZqhcXRAh/a/ShabWVx8@jzF9VMrfSB9dLmf/tuOnElCCd/pq6venKKBSDFa2SsaHAOgsehcSYvDmWeYHi23hLS45LXB1oP5EyGx@sDHnOcftBscEhEps9CbhQmRRR0Uz0HBoV6ZEaOGNa8JINCdIjTxj6azBh60MDgNUGoeasrLSoDvkyuHvssBwmiUSYDXNzwHJ02R@M4GGVxyN4z6kdhTKTnMvDGCdlFe0y90lZwLmM5el4mvWM2BrRn/CKrZXMlKs5ivbRRJhfoXA7aRau@Oh1mM@rpcK1Sg1GeIOrp6fCzTPYroLrjQqyHaWx5lWc7V4taOfP@vWeMmCxfx4v8fA@IicWrw73DyvHJ5snzY6iF60Cw7fJTfoGsQS6ig7sdp0sW54AuONz6BPkTvo2FINo0TSSk6BFLAhW0llV5kTsjomki9h3RZ8X3zEj4TQAh09oWk8J@AbjAIGZDqmHhB320m8dEXGH7i7jMwt4DG1BIGDxFNUOWEqlkVgJiqUCse5KKzS/sI@53H4rdieV2sj2aCYIUC9OrhuG8iDNJcP0rKXff8Ly/f7k5ltvLTTC3lBtAQ98gzu7m3v7zo8pktKCTJ6lbWs@Js8VcOGNL40O2wNgZmfQQEXGbQUlmMkXgr6Iz4yZXTf/ShGIJ4djs8cjEoZR/WRozJlCmhFZ/a0ILURTKAWo3qIhMH32G8VQki0EfHUF3xYsYCoFdOUQdZFyTBeYYWa/V8BMUA7EKcgVN75CEuJDXcS@q/qSCFodFwz564PE2N6erCnsdj8F/pFcKXNkaGzLRnek1prIsfLumfQYFDmATRd5HsUVOCHmR510O84tWRyFPrTcGrezRkR5xZBh66a7R9wJVMMaeOb5ZYG8HDpklCYRJqF@QwVuDGwmmquWmb8ncCQwpQPEN@i3Ct7d7XELtjKtmJN@jPDewsaMCIG6vVxgO8F20a81PdHPDmZzkjrDRGHSVNDvmCZtsoZbgsQvLs2B8QZXQRh2nC5ISSyMKjjafySAN2@x6oJO0oPsGDcXHrhaUE43OmfLDpqrN5BjwpBaqjCkmSwjrlW7a7IOu9BIHPK955EWCI8xeBGd8Y0FVgXJnlh0YeC6gxWeaGCow3x3gNtJy/EaUIAsFcqkdv9eNAM6wXnpqpj/@5u9wi6WnPrh/KNzDzBa8/bp4a4P7N4IQXYe3fxa@ZeHtR/ztVRqr7KaZxnE@Q4sbc0/mAnM@lm8UDAVDYOqaChRWOVb3i71D5jXRgjJWaA@GreO6QjETjFOY1QPOuKCKRnCewrgex3iUKo4BgbmASVDHQbWG0jPdmoIW@wrpNGYcF/w02s9rDvkeGzLg93aAhmtBE0uv5lZX9DRkUr0IEJJNoTM8XsgRJhIFEIzShdUvvW402cbGBpO9ptE1S6tFziDpRePVsvw6zOgiwEp8tFBlEAeijGNAWFlEUxaNpJ7AqNibxfU4CraWw/kNVEKFHACSQG87sEICOqcjSAXMbJtDn9SmUTAKAqltOxGL1QEiFRBx3GhedbpNjo8M4ix1pJVq0WqQXyIYTdMU5FkcW33FTv1TuybM7DLgvp/N4F8b3P9khu1dzlloZemm0Vdl2mQrloY9PrYdnOzfhdwyJZvOLqf11USEQ2WBCvKL7f09oIQWDhKjaVpvnL63uV3Z@@Lg8PiG8S@CjE@DxVm8vJE8VbVUtRY64mG@J4m6tZs@frq1G5AymqvxdDtCjPdPT2dzVmrTOZ2T@kt@OvNm2hRwIyE9c1/ENFen7tI5hJvYx6HpCOA2Pxx2I1UlcXVdrW2UT@3YjeTfzzLoHNOWkLnAdeqROef4dDYxi@HlDSd4eYOnBaYHdLQ7gAdSfed8bMVAeEQCOHiABSSApKUDqHnCEzJwwOd/xuZ2svz2CI9EH58jIjO7YY4ikCfBPRPYtMbWIYVZxI7hdbpWQ4IOvIWmQrlRo8BqT2gOSfP6XctXEhJNgZRQDQIhpojbJoaFoUa7BBQy6ky4Uuw2S4sBvoQEjQDwxQ8HXocdOv3IzNaOGbiOQBthOwO@hGyyLwY9gGvT48hEEWuCfqJCZCBUPMwqH1VDyxKGFodJNGYJ6VXR3KIouNZr5ZRhQuuYw5Z1BgJcSaSgpX@mg1oVmoLAQpPxRTsOMo5T@HM8lBcl6SfZ2xyOkRtVQ7PsljlU0IBUoQb6KfrHL19exBPyDR4go5/bgZnAKeufQUM0fNEixpYzpxrbenjFxJR51vV1NMKFVi2gWiDFY9/dByf0T0q7Z/SZMiCztB7TGL0qp4qd8nw3wdQyt2xjs2SSRtXwoADQmhG0TS5iHKbgLKSSLkHtoK9nt/Dxzuqzqq5pNXBTIgm2iDNq29CV41xUQoJREkQpENoS1i0rYI4492qc8yAOhktkJ4@hbdYZwWRNleahHaQFlZqVH0bsi41bIKfq@npB1MakqFlnwBY3pbyWBrQzREigpQJ9hZECoBreNoDXUuAaFYiFx1@atm0CgYBnegb0wcYAmMxNpILrZVJj6/SUQoxn8YmwegAZnbRaX4lfdXEjw2K6SJMzxWvoU1@fYqfaFt3qKP0/p7V08UpZ7JZGaVB0EmVlsVPSk8tLyeSivaQs2tjVP3yIczrXi6BJ1DUYIg0BSF3sJorAz6B5lBbt4qKxoSy2StkligGvMEi7gggfvLR2tWhcpxcfQk@dAh@XN15l0SPDpxlN068hf9hCFtMp4JkrtBNJd8tg8otWMol50BbrmIEP6dPjJMns0@M0TR8VhTaaPuuJ5jYlVcOauHGzDieg8BYVDYI9i4JdHDapB8Bjm/XLs8Lm6B484S/xPB@jLcSmF1X/5cmQ@wsWIe/iZJOOm5nllmeBgEMFiIivKSORAGHyi1/E9FUmK4uPVpe7F8l4LlOEH724xnLss8XT7EqMxR4bhg9D9vTS1elO/uyCme3s6ltVrVpt7W3t8Pzw8KvhKHGqxGPbB69kfQVA19g6fe/7WWPZOR/2aZ9YbCktxdJL@sO1dPr169eg8uKnWtbKAYhWS1TVeK2qrAmPXnltbSm1ml9KHT2O1yEvUNyEks0mjpllpdmp1fdaLfg6HbrpSYnxD3v0CNMDB/wz4dcbtsk53DTPzgYVY8T9rdgAH7u@iPv0m5cvX6LjJX3YuyMRP8YxCnSxQt3IxSiT2Uz2L/904Tp1dVjf@Mvv9dLmAj4O8PHD66foPtZzny0sfLa1tbKSAsJx9@E3h19vbm6u7KRyh9XcoxU1s7DxF3@@sJDNbmTTCzXP02vx6vlXcjazImt/@fvx@uHhdzwP6w4/y0wHJ/7m4auzXI6ds3fwOW8z/Cf3u1bEbaC70X6HHSQoyyUSNvF4bjl@/CqO9fMuput6bER/dSraAtPLj9b@@48P3sb8WDmbfunC04@9ja3mY9wJDnhbDt4uYuXYBoKtXsdG6VKpBM61//7vIH75C8CDIaMN@CnnAlyro1hZLVGU97HyKjj0bBbS/X@@@10pVh5CJsrlvV2WLWeXBJvo@Yf6Q3LZfgcUjNOYnl85eEyvlvn4IJvLbqDbNvGGnA4MR1HI6Hr2lInK00UVYnF1/OUerANurFMnxgLQcZ2zgKPYyxjxBzAI8Qh3Cw9iG@7xchru5alhLK0lV7KP7eLLyGfi5Vf/OcKLyFYXHr/eSac3ytDP46dQeHxaF40szdbysuM8xqm/ItsXvkX8GTqq6gA4fE/JU8WPIF8sX0rVOYmCNhaEsPEbi3rFBCVZ2Jx@CbgKfv7qP/7VT/7qx/T3E/r@FykWbDNSqxe1cvAB/pHLrnx1Kl7tp@wp/9g2/MM3eEUf9ACXLWYmY@GnXMYf@hdv5KLnlJ8IKYcvBDGOMheOBfKK0pViH9Jphi2AXQSFebxQWMgXVgvZdD0oHhWD55wcTyOlG5dPlOcRfBbgj/7hE77i7wL5CG8CuflZYOX7fGZ2AFKsGqvWarxNl6MVdPvnSEOm08RbPdqlXEgxFaRUMnkETMoEb8PnNHnH5zl8Na0u3tLaGGtMiv3KP2WJxa7gU0uq19dV7VWyWBT/oN0Vwzf8cBdkrXatqhuvyslklbJYLYu8xlec@KrzeENltTIvAP1q9VcbgD65Ud0oOdv01YhH1NqrcnVjEgd8NtRa@fHjJJL2MSAoL9YYjCugNq43rsvX1Y3r640N@N@g32vxBN/rjRv/9Bh/5sCMw2tY/6fVdPk0LRpluQbvWrqMPlr6FBxleAJctSrFrpBzWLVGxvtKalVfzdVURg1kCYRXuqAvZZfTueFnq5UsyAAPwbOynF5Cx3vsK0HbWZdiOG5Y58OHdfJ4/fHb/wu/px@//TfwClnDWxIptPEW//bf4d9bH/9Omvh39Bb/2Mk7/Dvy8e9pA/8OPfw7eYt/mw38O@nhnxQrMQYa3OKjTDdzkdHP9XNwWCwDCnQn09Fb0PmwjMkyo8yIZXqO3gKXCX8ZcFmZNsucsYydsXUdAsHhs4yPrjY8zuCvDVhc@LMyGUSeuWCQShe7NLKDTc/3dZY4laos/toEtUvTtYy2atVrudX@22q8VoylT0/TXBdl2ZUi2T2/vmasXq8826nX09geTp86B@P/g4Ne9PXW/96B8/TA6Tnwf3Bw8PQURFo5@TipPoZPqZzcEI9HsXLx0WlBRV4OuDqW3nh0Wl5W0b2aBEbNol/yEz9jjPAsL5xKMFZ/@fKySP1u8fKieFkkR/jKHXUBIMC4A2IVRX8NPhDv9GWa@thL@FwQXnpD5yUEBi7uSL@8PEWNEsYP4T@QI/r6K/i3/v/1//Q5U6q1BDSCq@sNhT4J/Eskrq6vrsVvOaEo4kXZgD/0gHeMcnVdRicBXYGrqiRqietr7ge/SmKDIyxjGhtlijwGBOERC9OkdPmP8qt9Ytr8cxoHxQlG1opYFjw9HWYyiWIDfMK1AeM9rTAlirT3ZrGBq4IwmtQTBJFbKRb1Je7OrmSLxRXxspYvFvPCvago6zc/5cwjfRW0g5WVRKJYzAhYGDcWAyegMD2jWcRGXowlMLO85SsZnJ2kG0/ickF@@FARd@Q86vcTDx/q65n370Over1lufU6@i@/fy/XZdymU1rPwXsm//49CJ14wnGVZw5fIFZUnX2WLVMK644LpVqDYKans@M0O4Zn@L6rvLP6KRn3uXpygqyUZzKOexr/@Y@@973TeAk3bpDvio4IMBWW29hYXSmXV1fAvZqHgsuLfCeQcpZc1xPXi2mZF5fJi/GYCNLzawnyvY5jOIttsEdlaKgeftjVdYzqj63kEkpjZCauwCfw09fXuSdbWVXyyXXxV1pIsPISE3/VanU5ubK0tvS4BhrPzQ8K1eKVUYqn0/Hr0pVRwFms62JT3IaBJ9CMhw@X14GY@UzxVKrXdzZPNut4kSau0UOHyNCTJLSE6699N16lKcfceq2KBaudxuOF4mOqdj2fY7F4UcCpcZD2LL9O5Y95nmS18SjqkLDClz/gdynWZ/raMnSz0MtKfdortZZhLVxudpnTbi@AJ1Qca@DOAM/sdoPrQy4dt9u6tFrmghQ73N/crpyksqCxxLK7m9up7PHzrZiOr7nxOwaz2DJ6HFU2dw6eQ4zD/crmceXzvReV54fg70lv3hmmaZgD07ysDwaXb/GKCbNu9sF3/KmbTcsz3rwx@vSBQQuXzB9/9oOPP/tfPv7ejz7@3g8@/t5Pfv7tT34A3z@E74/480f/dj2Hvz//9p/9wcff/T3w/C/w/c/w/dOff/vb3@Vfev8z@P7XiN@fiW8Ejn8lwPXrP//2x7//829/46fw/Rfi@9Ob39/809nfn3x//hfj/fgPbof50b@D7x9xXAHsj36X@@HzBvzvcrjf@OnH3/oP/P8vxB86f@/jb/0Z/oiXf/rTv/ivH7/3n7LZ/F/8648/@NHH7//44/e/9/H7P/z4/X@c/fjb/1rPRH/@4ONP/vh//Mkf/Y8/@d/o/w/p94/u8//xp//0r//9X//ff/0n4vun8P0P4PrTv/5PwKt/@8c/w/8f//Hf/uef4f//@S//9o//97/99X9Fjt/hjv/3X/xb/vs33/vB33z/n//N976d8/uDW3@/vYf/t/8APvfP533w3Kdcn@rz7S@Vn78PNcapAA/QVR4sCwrs1sikyYvPhgXpMxYrL@EH5HE1n80nl0D3XFpfB6FcI/8NBGEStNOf/JOPv/1rwP6/Bcjg7X@FN/jnLxD0Q3phX301EciSNCGiJr/6CgPFEPKrKNQPweN9GjTxzOP3APEVBfMPC8Eg3f@DwACOCbAAbjIDBIP7Pbn/z7/9579PAWFc9P61CZSZwDsKvYjg74Oi/hDb/bg0Uegfouj4@LPvfvz9f/zxZ7/z8We/jp2DurKe2kxBt377jC8A5u4Bh4Cr94EDQB2HkDDkX5Cy4FjYwFlKSU@@fg25XwAXDLeWpNwyvEl6mdw6uiFiEt4IyXCYxF/4l1bWGb6Az5B84cmSELSVxCvek9KwBGEEinfDM3SW8@A1xKmGEuDFSDxOqp6HgQwbbhEWiFlKHrH6UmnIIybRo0wYkG0k9DqS9ayczJd2IMHScIchLkSelF7D83WpnC8Ny4juA2UBcCS3IEmAwqvnk8PyB3gvEU6Al4Y7HyAr@VIyWc6DTwkLmaTUUnVKU89R4ajsSUblRn/GcN/lo8fQZGQ9L/OpECAlE9D4mxxDIyCAQ/hpckkUh/4DJ32XMD7U05Dow/14@CP0pvgCAPCqKm7Xg6@qYm4eQ/CQo0pSsvBIcgxAuSRpUAFK8CCNJSklqX6T9ALpQx4@7bOBogLRYXEWFxfBtVGWl@X6AYwfYaDmnhc833BxOZGUyAKTV9dl9Ma9T3xX5@IhDTSXdpbgV4f/ygLtZKayFJekxTjOYsR51pLssyT/Pn68xD6DstNz7CcxNbnsrDgxXsyNZFLOQpJlB96WqIhJQoSzDPSflF7FJBajuofGkuK/8NBK5B9pSuTxqiQlx@849yhiaFpKS6XEU6MneWjCoVGoeGqLpDIyPuahRWumr66whKTQJWoJrKGmScqY9NQ723KGMN5IyXJKX8WFqISYtjkpZLG1SpVCBn6/dgqF0gd9ZU2CJ70P8DI3ca0Y8A1eaa9tbGD9l69UmltCJ6isq1K5LNbgmS6VjysnAH5ywPRsRmMwVrlaWcuu5FZy2eXV1dxaVl9ZXV9ZzeWXQbKuZnLZrL6@srKeX1@7Dqn1GIRTqrDUyG2U/9GNz//0j2Z9ZvviRyp/xYYaTadfS@Vuie8FXcT1ePk0IxdpootouVjNpPAvu7wMv5DPlJ5bqy0sdK9ULPYpbUC8wh0PkFXpSsWO7wF8mPRAYg/ACz6QBq5IMrGHZO@gKPYL4J2sfM@ArOeAkaEeToGTOTqo0aurq8hXii18843PymUYc6h7u1IM2mCHBSvkqtXSOhpdpdoauCaFnjG2s/di73jv4Jm2s3cM44CvWXY5o0mx6@vrdriuQ68mOzg4kFD4weBuWcf41002GAwotAHv10ND6kc/xf7UR8pm1eyyuqyr@jL@3@HI4v/94bPwn8VfiLWclfhZzC4e6QmmztaxoUsb3LpIGW8CdIxWKbwwlimJq1ap5TTpqE6xXarWNA9qpNjSGk5rpHn@CEZ@Lcvrd41RKd7oOs3zeBBo4RVCeC6utJB20xpuV1baiUfZ1bXCAm6lIx@mtBn45dDvVeBJYLn1QksLkn4K9Qsxs4Xsau56Q1gPK0PGMQNlTO5K5KJgwwj@GveoFow2lPeqyfd2FORsLi9fP@6ZLctgpxk8AHU1E2x1Vb4O4CAhHCfi@F3p4d0duNO5kDnNJObEzUBcyB9lS9oQdkrKtDRfhSZawysNq7WNwIJJWfrw4cOQdsMU9mxfbIvJruTRn0kolx5Ch/9Q587c6tiZQecJWpt5BjUCgsVm@7i73XfYicN3UW@ZzTkQ2x2Dbnjcdh0YTP/yMFuGfc6Ddixu9iIMemKg3WuvZ/mdORDP@z08sGi6/2AYKr0GZBAZiANswY/bdZxZAGvs@eGcUj4NrVThDhoyUwXgR3ufPzmJPE8qm9tPpFW2dfBsZ@qRE0A5tl/ZPQlf13hoEDUXovi6sr8//Soe0GsVafZkgeXWcAdt8KKzmOEbcqouV2tFaKj@Neh2@WLLHjzSHz7UN1ZXD/eBmusAuMpWyvnltUyhsJhm0BZeQNlKW2Ry47zQx525nlmuDA9dPGlor69AqT@oGwP2nIQGzndcFl0T1J58tuAvSk9xz@66zg@gWZ5Ep0Dx@kC8KtSX0CRGy7m06Wxdozsw2aDP5nrCA73Q6VpnHeiXL50AQGoYBoPvp34gfnS2Beh1q4fP0yC/GyHdGeC4ScRqs4ykcQKt53P59eVsPpVfz6/k9NVcLqVnU/pafm0desSMntdX87l1PZVfWV9egW4bQnPra1IMejKrnU6DbqTLMjwLgNZu4o03G3h1kKN1ylKMT2iyd4qRgBoP3wdMNiGOjHcvgljFYwlLVknOruCZoWWdAUaDNVlsd3c7s7sry1v4gust2xlZbuFLLp/JrG3Jskkh26BaZGXZ4XEgCMB8/pLJbG3L8oAjQPtZstzBl8oqDtxk2cKX7c3dXUznDb5kMT6AnfMQ/tINXtYAzMaX5WUa@cny2xAdwG3yhFYopxV8wTQxZJeHbEOYLH8e5CeTAQxHHI5jeBKUdXNTlvf4y@YmhnxBBc/xrH6JL5v0kWUXXoAJZfkMHGfYC8hyA5zIirLcBFdzZIAf3i6ENpVsaHvyiBMISSTLQ4I2mucyjE@EPybz5MkTo@O3zDP@Gbn82YSsQYg1HFR2G59/3jg7a7ijzcrnRxjyxRdPjDejgds4a4hojTp8HIgDIee90fQH8rhXrxvdmSFfQog9FVIf1U3MW914C3kSnzNMpFf/AkK@gJAZk8JDjg0@PQBt4GerB88to0EhwYdC6DlsNOQiMqo/6ps4iYtt5twGWZDqGU3XKeL7sLTA4ko8NaquZmpF8mc9hSWuMsVrDG8rdIMt6vagA16NqsNSpgbj1rWsONukyKfDbM6SUwu9R/p6rrBgPNKzK8lhAQ2kO@04i6v6I0V/uPROeQbKxvJKQT599EiVq3rtUVbPF1bXXi0NZDlRwN9Hy2uFd6D@x0HHx59Eda32aC0XibK2ljTS2cIabgJLFK@BIj70RI2Bb9brinJpGueJBOYY@3fQqai4bERFtYptZZgalnjG2ChRHJb0IrfuwTI3cLXQvNQAL4vkGM8A3fBRpoAT6Yqsr@dlSD@dVhIJlEooR@D5@mWwzhc@Io4JJ/9orKDym2b1/GpCw5Mydaddp9v22Oso5HiRXHqJh9voYHuwB5XGnl5BOsFxD3YHpFFZDbzimswUDKUhN4zG@GSYvrYuSWWh9h/y276K4vXzJ9sajATEG5qr0nZRUXVcDW/k9idCuCmlwOsE@jTtiYk7S5uB3zY/cq5VhjDMQ203CNgXx500YWFCO3lSvFLrOCP/nZPzk5Nv1Oso2mMYAvGM4NGcIplgwEPuaNzLajGjVAaXAYNthXIJJEhcEjnq5XKpXuqZvb4/gjIH8b7kJnjHiPY8XpjwyBBFv8JjdCKgXspcj@GfDXpsiwPRWbsgWr20BfTNFG00jWni6yIbxoZSuYWWv7ZKW1eDAiqh10WzZLqu48oxPKD4yC4NbM9om4emi2fj9g4WWZuZeAqt2Xl9WkHIbVSmr9Wyy@yJfCiGWm4kJr0ir0g65TshRa5odzeuF13DUEN5lSi@hTd3kSktbSvxaKXYUrZYPQE@mdft122WZasrRboIQkFMIA6IckgRI1EqfwmIOd7zQgEyIljiHHBiQotQI1aLQoxE37ounpWqCP0efzZUWa6pavV9TSoXpTJIl@IoZpS8QYNf2ZppwLh8tTgEP31tpdhhjVLj1bDolvowkmTFLlS7GCHzLesGbl8GIgGed@@Vj7/23cSGmitxvyLhet8FRaKu1UvDcQUtl6pZGD9nV1dwPL26DF8dxtVZ3JCZymbWU1kd9AnQMyA@fNfgfQW@AAPqRlbHUbfSVWCULKcyw4ymp3RTTymZ11brdSJ1roD@RwRLpHynYgPXgAcyD7AsvcLTSCSzS12l5TBjQyX@BWlXpEIaqQ7rW6kOojkyjS4HT6hseUnpLioIs3gy6FeqtUKhMux/B4MU9e2j1eRaJvkukSgqCyxR8sy3RGEUjESC/gJws5hJYN6gV80sQKGh/anXUNP@or6WLVQHi1VVh9Jl3p9tyGW5BlV1zST4iy5Ggr5VBL9ABnINbaxjjf36qFB3TahWfT1bFCBSX0hkRVZO5eB0hRKPr2Xj8US8iPNnC@AvJDqJ3zh0B/GH@iMZdDy5IK9nIXwsyG/kgA/CV3Updi3h6JXBcDx2JV1fXW9Ed6N9yUYjI6kGrw8ZO0suSixNu0S0eowtkEvVyjTLuVnaPDvaLArozW0pVqANk@M9bexUHI9nanrhU/emJDfKr/jzFLdmQbISmaSrshotNZsWjp3YCzwt9IjFoVyG26tms8u1anYN@nKQwQFoNgtF964kTm@@mSm9kSyz9KkkyyR9@Mp3PpfgpWAfYtTe2fZVMEdReIpDZqYYBd6@q7XEh2dW9yq/rPJht8JiH1gyrdF@vHr6Qwz6x2uqhWDv5ZevszmoF9sJPGCA7YNoh@40l5Nxps98zfrH66/WXuVfPX1@8Pxglz3OFPKF/NRU/@njVEqP6/EN9hg0euuoAqO198zJ6R/sL/gG1VgxVujHl1fiy9NRS7FhaSXY2qDo5bKqb2TZI@BiVgDJ39ZX1cz7MmfJMgWsZiHk46/9dGW4kYf3LGjOBaBpLpktl/WlbCLW//jtv8EDlleVF5v7LI7mLv7uz38/u/Z3f/4vaR09fl1Ev@zyWgwg0amvrsWurvpXV9fw4WG5WC3G87SylgA33@Ohx8pp4a2v6YmYp/I3yG4u5r0X9m@UbCYPYdsH/E1eBWrG1mNSLP/09XvGNmAoXW6dnVlZcqXTN9ZOFgsw7oR/9gHnSj@oC69L5cU0MABO/K5jhGBub6lcLi/hogyLl5N4WDibo7Wh6nWxBkTFD47Vlmz6M70l/MP3V9xjyfPgPQiGV5yX3zBZrqwzGN@l0x9/7bez2dW/@/PfPE28r7@vfwMieH19fVXPxn4B@bjlBF8wQKOpHTyLh45wYMfmXDqpNWUphjeRthmHD4Z5OLDD8@vc@g@@SReoZxCJ60BHA7RqhcCW8BxSivRrOrScKEpSqISS/uyeNVOEgy2hhV9oO9KV9ACDoPdiJZBa0oMxKvDoodmgZt3rDtw@aYMKxdNrKfYQokAKD9DQxAKdnxKiT9WLLL10MyrPMrc5Q/oG65meh5amQDJLDyDKPnApXRXE@gaewUNIywZRqyEI5ZMCWlVIuwZpd3mEOvkqVHoOkGI8dzySDQq29AAPFJECDp0yszYAoMgS0gMgAJRBEYitGttgywl2ZSWTxbFpqmvcBYd2CYzghI@E0RBbC4@1BZGLCGdx8xMDF00yMVHDTTPqGSDhOPiSTQmGBhid3lCpoUN890YFuOgwt0JFYw8fjnNVKlmtBKMSIX60y4XmtMZ2hG4kAMiCcdVnrYKcYnYyiZX9YJLtgOJJyi5wnUqOMVAbj1rh67Ukwf@9mRY5cqqqKKCIBRD1xVtFE0gGkZHsvA6baFlMz64lWJj5JuS9SZkiEyXhYPF0@JlGloKaPIvX0i9igYlMCa/0joxqBN9OH/FiIJcGeGkSnl/nwkAc3uLXaaBw2vOD2GEsKIrVJei25cL4gJafAmMnyrKewGjt0IfyQbvfsisMN6blEvigWAiNJjEMNC8h0lmgyWuyy@X1HZvsUdDZXty@R1bCPIlb3@DZHtiXBlmW4qnQbrdIjri5LuR8siZlc5NZHo@LS10NFwa7AW1SzDzTyPBKdp0p3AAcTi/aIboERaIMw6jQQBo3umYPsnRsmgxtIniFdPoMlIpBg4wgPLWArzq7FnQbtpcW1zOlL61zK32C1v1Upw2Kqjh0F0M9xArtEQlLA2ROrGudm3ywqkycmvRYdjUFimAKKDv@AmELOPWKJyMzEJziUPBdg8cad@ZTkbgLyihx87msLyj1BKkFZCrGxSuYLgw7Ql/6vJfEENMbecGRaDqjB@9aKHKhZfJzUXE8GBUe2JPE2e0SnSvWcE68r4A6FZzkQycon@YFQKi6hH0MCM1mcMQQWzGU9gF1ANT2oGWhzRDfLeDZ2xJa01Ka0PSEgLfZZ2w5Sxfb89Po4vA44MCqL01ihzCIiuXw/BZUjMbnGUCuQOvstSAshiZ0OPth/IC70U32c8bszRYEOux0KK0S480ieMlFXrB1cGtoUPQFCFyFHM7IyYIiJwFtUk7IHHUYfzo653aJZEmB3cSUYohBkBqwoKqwZXjcPqMw@HF5eamRzZmBa2mmh2ZYPbxaLt0/s0AbddK@2euLGzQsvP5IXO02dqncDDPeRPhoSBcArj8c8acktfEU7NuB5ZpKvO3FsQ@8AFnZP@vRgX48au8R3@xaZJa4qdCKqCfYLFtLXQVsVkA2U/Pxa0TCGKIZpkapZgqQpRrN81T7slUUARfU7gA5VJYZeKI5ODd46XmBy@q3QwjHp420wXuje950ug6qHjKfSx0nzUsYQI6CV/Het4YQyTYv2abrGiOFwhMIjXyqjEi7YSPo3SkEnNCbsCtuNckaVke1iejDMDr0XeH6qIvH@aWr25FyY1UYPuThQwgf8vDhONEg2eqwxjUv9LrG4iBzo3WeABLRjAKYa25raxxCmEEvZjpHgZCjCb9r@DZLFDugN3@DeiwFjAE8QSbuFLStVz2t2Z55uVRLps@Ap2UiBNQ4oK7WiKaXrdCN1O9edPuON@Flo/Ea6HxEvtGr2RHcwHkFyxhWEDEGp5eFNk7OehqfUeH9vigwYEB1CwJRA9j0FStRDG2LUiAwTlUe05hnrCoyUyMlSwQJP9CKOOk5YaOIahFE6B8WCbIJISxoOcLIthACL128jzSAVekWCDKSGq/FgZJTTYWLlCJVUiRXqhpkE8iOWmlpuihBOFRFdSooUsxrUf/R7C98cvbb0C5m554YlvcLRSnaVMwhmoQ0RXMhqrJyKVKvkIP0ktE1XeigKlwNFZ0yJLOUDkYTPB0sAjdlqkQqv5ng9UNnFGRbLoSsMCqVoIijEm@WvF0EJOUED6N5ItooYAQRnwsQwJGZGc0U0YbRaMNSiQsONpwT7TKSySFlcsijcOjhnEzWRDQYJIXGMrF6amgjDRQqGfDpvLdEe6Ay84wLNPrK3qBNExg8BWmOZQ5xgeAh1KSRz5q1malXI5mOCK0pBMiINxC0@J0eBWla4Olq@BbKKE7KQEbxN8EGXFYAg5EILnK7VUrIZDTUBb1eTlI/AG1XTlYlWccdSfSX4V85FXgGX/2mZ2YSUp/0zKSm/v5BPGtI2UgDjSgZemYFBTIOWDbJjAeoJZcOU2Yoz@CfDi5tTTe6TiPdM3D7BN7uHF7lmgjGA2So73Hf8Q3fWVkp8EGQRfz1XICziD19PgawzmwHhhpRu3gWt@Nnx9FcYdM5sy3PTOHlsVwFN2nBnxuslqJ6r3A6niSJWT8@LEXUnIFQda3X8eKhel3xzG47UQiNTuKrhnwYj0s4ngVXJD7IIYH0oK84eHO2n7gbJxqNFNFOrOa5ctAXgXFIZJOBsGqCPg@hHVBVmOeMR4JkzQ1V44avkFHvjtNzzkC9Q0uNGHsK/d4YN2bI6PcpLylm4BC1EDGtSc1BaaaMhIj65SdHZV9mFSMRxs9OIpggRoq50zRGyrozkqvPTY5HC9I7/vT8Hkfze3x7fmlUPZ1nPtQu8cBPS3pZGWMAwHE2lu/ORkoYRr6RnYmshN6oQPEI985ii7YntTCnmwC6KcC1NvBHKnzzyFyLyPiLefS/vQKD6JX7Vp@B97Adj0De9HAXnEIG671gMVAB8L0Eyp6byYWsvXPPtAAWLe3voq4A@ioJLhttAUHD7MMw2pPDxRCB@A6ex51IN/ietieVeOCMPLkXKXaenV9FO/WW2TVGZksRkKkI3qDERzAyI3l1v4KjoCOh5/BBnQKdVCJqSBiJzoEKc1jGSF1EzEjfgOEgVsg9NPNNOdybTz8MvyGaccquxGefQeGPx2NkcZwMxPdH/RG3odjll4QIOcr7H16TeFLzboIAHcQ@htQ42cRt4vNICYt0jx4hhNUmi0zWkoJuy@n1b9bhp5Ho7pJC5UYilYJanrDyPK/GrdtqPMIVAU/y9Zz7seRdTHdvnouwGkc2FmHbn9aF3MCM@xeaTSWKkfvcWmOOfUMmoB/Nu9lzepX6DIEaxiRJ51s0rib9IiHhEHgPnjiB9AKeiPDM9OucoYKy4RyVuACEUUjP6Ee0FuED2jhgiVAxsOVP2YhASYEbwK@uwzSbc9Ns3kizOZFm2AImk4wASc2JJEUtYPXcVgVds@3Pkc4YhINkeNwmtuFjO4aL0xJXcStesFIsfhEvgECOm/FCRQGhHG/FCzvk8OKFY3KcxwtfgmPctuLv44WgWSCAC6/keIz@QoTjezNe2FYS15KP1y0E6WrxQlinAPOIvxJFgBRYbtAaccnMdkQxfdeEjo2UyhRDjvFSOE6iCZcUfTPwz@2q8/s/IBDnLJcImCWZPtFpRHoMng50G4HFzRktuSB688rBLu3/GRuuh/AkDOaicQg9qOGx@KQw4hnDUFqhgCdkEOVmYXaOmD55u8E9siNSBw6lSp5Mn6inkT7QUii8CsC1xKTRfBE/qK9JFLwC75dPjDwvnzeyEyRHOcI11sSMbCFRX8dvKRTW9dSNELz2ozVEc9eTQHhvYQDCa4nQRmQ66HC02IaJ9Z3@JJNQKO7qs6JxaPaNN0rk3qloJBVEy5wTTN6iZCgYoo0/cVtxIvEwaxMiCAOrmRpvZWG/QLIYg8ayLqKp8sYHWYjIHGjhZvPcRLbdEU6C4@ImRX3FvG4oiMuTJMk1KSYhsoYmJwaGz1MPB68VNETxacPXIOYQJ1UURBCJGabC5avzCfq7w/X3QKEOiDCVwCzFenZXelO9vrWXncp5d5zszQrEwBTbScxUjsIUxiSH0UFEM7@N126o@LiFgyv5PNEQ@5S2H5AtHBPcQbfpsQXHhVqCezHpeZ4Fz/PsfELd1Ei6F1qgtGiYksDDCx7mdFy02/PKCz6rijGEJrKN7idXsDtZwdHKQ3xUAHeK5LyV4xlCXNsat20yZ4o@KFL1AuOCnJY/w2oee4K4p6XYcBkWPA7qRzsHz/a/hk53bW0tIfro0Th/2GpxUjXsxzlm2nsc9gczhi3ZFJrzxsVrnHene0AXTm35hizhwhqUAbzGJGA/0cYTQpZF5PlU24V4HDZCUYHrfNwMjAmphKqOgV22JejqA0FMX1kyBJJAvQV6p2i0lsA5WeAOvBGtXqfuq17HzUj1uujFsGqCFe7EL2IL6YHn0gWM3NjwpUQ2XhjbOWAvn2yesJMnFbb7fPtL9vXBc/Zy89kJnpg9fL61v7fN4Ft5dlxh4xkF/OAFDDigBLrumE2z1wCRnc1kVrj1mG2nP@JyR9lOcP9jo8eeOE0T16M2PKP3uMNfNNv0yzxWBYajI3GXOGS0Z/k@v7ysCehIuWnRwTTcws8AtgFj2h6OeXtOy2pbACvh2LdvmV5whop1LahBkLfBAcgUV5LwMgjaCkQXgdEdbngJGMDjIg2gMbzxpXOWxyOYLY0JwoWfT6bgSeXo6THbfLbDtg@e7eyd7B08O2a7B0fwevj13rPPgZ57xydHe1vPMYgAnx7s7O3ubW@SB89ARmN4JppudbstCxqCE1Wa57jETReqhm/RWWcAAw2eXRp0RM9j8YGN0scyutY7sxUvSnhNDD8WSGsCLLykjZlvcSkzWPOl/QTyc48uOlnMsA1KDRpLGdpbUTRX6PbQ5DQuPPRGDC@8MYt0VFkh9/giHdqU07JMJm/jnhOc@@YnmqktB6ghoQXAjaiCDSglRvbb4/HUBqEsQ2rNroNGt3hqfFOgeMGoj4OtI0WJKCb2viBS3Nm/Z@N8kF4MPYDvwSMrkvVdDsCWQw8OwFa4B6qie7gXhOUExMA/GKB4Zqvc402vv0vrv2wt9NgyaBSbF3ni9UZVarDxRc1Wr98lC/x8locu1jG8pmVRFI/g0YJ9txvcbtcwgeVBJoq7iHCvGkDKIGzauNQgtrHZA2rYEArcgPt@jLbvMaWU0NgJbvYxbYtfbXDWNWy@pWm8FYd4j@XRXkVJ7MO2wjsDWvyWdGJAvMdjMh9hvB2hFZr3jQcxt26kaIg9j3TvTLCl7K4MbN3IwC@DBhCpEyOdJvVUdFoT0ThtwcqK5wBH4rzthyg8sHNr0DQnIgR3D76x3r1LCCKnJsZJwb5Dyh1UEV7TmOJrlm3HhTZOYrWHJ09QCjY7Tt@3eB0qkyUY3xwF0NixQWqvS@WJ1Oi2yKkUbceOJNoALp6TagOY8j6pEsfzRfJQfAVtPby6ivbRYXaMhnNhRtbOUriIdGni9AsowvzaPext6BJVoX9KY9nxga5CzJfKO1un6ofXKTS8z8UCv2wq2ETIr07sYVrQPGidjzYguqh3iZYW3N7gDRoYW@ypE9ISW3mADMaBHQvGdY/rxTCMbx@@6Y/HSqb9yfP9@xKPpaJk4hJ54HWUsXRLsWqQZIri1JjY6xGRnZBZkPVK4JMinKG8fownSLAWikARG@UIXXo6eWuCECFB6RqDNkgWcS@SqO4Qf4KVaetEoEjSR4nWR/qVslVKlhPp8c4RFiGnEojoVIAZr00a7z@h/uoGup3b0YH8vj@6/K25493DJ2HbuRXbJ@VNTc7HxbulCK77o/1wC1reuf1SaKHsqfmIeSd5E1vI6SFzphZj4e7Y21N8faPuqO0BGux7cQYlRBpJbWDTEnVgGVPhERJRNGOF6Phkp3J0xGQ@PoG4IPdwyNASYhBxL/BLJfjuWcsmYaeFSlM4WA6Vp8BnYutaeOTjlsY8k3hzRIXQQVKCHqGwmLzCkaSe6FlIhaDd9CQQA8pN5u4qkEFeVSC@RlOoILxiYzUsLKA0s5gx3vlYXnRTt6BbiuvG0T35tGOa9914GZM7iiKKbv4xzvCkyOz6e8n140KQDlewzLcDKnALNGm8j1Rjx5BwHwA1bbIGb6mWoEpx0zxXsGMB7XCHV2ZSw/77MxQxElfCuS4cEetCORZZ4/rxYqDm0M5D7AYM3NIpAvkOZQgIRDz5bEQrNDHu9JTJLgiUTLwm6HGUKyB67boY3iyqjPvJUqiQR9vaIuWmGuSyhrOzAndxPtBnuLd5dVo8TCcF0vbWpNRfTVK8l5hIKaD5zMIEgYB5NZdbvgv3dCmC6OrfFzfvQ6blp9/rw/h@jNIbeTS9D5y79ywVhI8Z4BbS8a3yQYOZigiqzow@ZaLs1BlF8wd54fNCkBm0N9vs4KVIk6km2HAqb7Ox8x4pip1AbpQh0oTDgvJWc4P617cnhwL5zvQWPj093tgQCPcIXv8iPFwXMZsS8cJjopN@puvaBMaPJfUcPD5Gp5FuPTNHh@b4hlZeGAykZbZoAdrikBHfVpsKphgoEZpV1PASNZzUK07P6ql6MVrC3b39ClsiQ2jtiSlI2ZUTEZGzYNm3ZYBEL01HYK9BR/E@8wrwhTykApRAJjqUpxBtEnfmjSgCynKVrPiLbZ9CpOrTld72moaNNjxSMt0//BAi0uRr5WA3MWtCPVOciA@Z8/q2ArFSsqrJFBX8cB4XMU2i4LWJ/pF@SkIr9mKD5C1XrhppPZ9ZXZeodHbKT/Wq67XUUrMkM@hzDbvnDdzL1vmZ07losy7rv2kMm6N3bxnLrTA84pt9yE0@6qslPN2qMDQQkmfrGWJYkcFHZL7yVGZMI7t9uJ7MxsPv4gJaI4QPjZULeAJiikvZUi/gQjwp55d61dVayS5lir2qXSviWT0/WfKTelJBj4fQeYJo4QvyVb@GXekvorOtpn3B3EFjBKOk8OwHo7Mf2L/jDJfYs03z5bTNWHqAm9XwDIlmm5dKeJ00cqaE@o/0gA7x6Hjam6aLcbalZUEOgPopUFa9If2OEtKDjDbo@w6FiIRUZCH23novPQhOHWVowgBAqlYtyM4G4RnDKLjuw31HfDe0qnNtTMejjokIiirGJGknn8oyHgHEjIqjV9Wa5Gmm0exgJvDiwPcUjW1s8BvFryGYJulwp4bh0sGHTA2duL4Bjz4tJmASpJh7dHxDguLju44O7kNTUD6dd6GN7hIpghiC27jZFR1HovgbQABO@AdcpdLEDKZQrEBP5Ef9aO4ATcZNjutxFQFPQfJKeYCFRdw8vdIYOe34JhphsoJM4P/gEsnJaQUfUQJVp7cbxQjhExycSELL0OLNQ1pSlVJQGR/dcTQlEk0NogXAEVI8uJMaOJEFo5@nJjSfEds2u13INKfFgzE50EnHcUX6yTB9r4pp1sLM83D1Rrg6Ea7xcJ6pMZQG/fcYqBAFkmNXY7hrJo/BUjfSKjHSTTSo6aYGGscYtngbrKf5Tt0aA5fDquRcGQZsTASokZBXM2qfhyxMxAkZPAyv8nDB31lR82EuJ2AfT6aPT0lUkEl7Y8VWkiku1Wyr@4h3TmEIspnM8Ip6Hh3rm9iON0pxZFKIE1DQcBqfmm25NMaS1AOJQ21GLm88ljWhTDxSprPBDx3eaFgz2kiESpRmkgg3pPOFkA4FL0RQEE5kNBa03HIQeSQijyJoEWohSJYfWrzRwKFo0028hMcY3@NP0NgnMxfAxWYHPuA5H/LC88PIkwQiobsgzybTpDTBYx/cUxTqll5knPZoGuNsIfEsMskbpmnyI9NtnOVeCOVEVFAEkuIG3cMQQekxgB6w77wqxMBr6RfpJelzA1Toftccsk0cRRh0mkqaOI@OJlM9NHVElle8Qb/fxUVFUuwu6cSzsM2RzeFqyhhjZBlNk/Zw4w6HT6FLnB@HSBo7QMyXuP9jHOANzs74ffQMLRyBaMUJFcvXpE17xOcroM0sZ/mpcJMNPL4oCoP5s2gmeM3x1oOUpsvcNQl0MQ@0HIkXtc3bt5gux2MhaGwLurSCJH1nYDXPtz/H5do1PbOsR0h2IVZ7M9ryyvigFBApCMhmQF3N6SuSFFn6bfKlXxURptg@dvQvgDfNC7w0V9qEHoMAPVBOPdO9MFuaJB2Z4Rov4kVWxoVHPDbtDNwmn7sB3Qov28XTvl6Kr3YBh@ET@2e@GtykpbCUhGtS48VkqOoLq4UEDA6UtB1c/KX1CDzVz@mBkXqmD0RZSrDJLNHSssgL6S49nGcCaqBZksjSQ0gG2/GtJtQMTVRJXUDFVznGifGrwSM5gfSaXQMP@WqzMoCnX8YUCDIQrBTdlgdJrIl/Uh6YKFiwhG4ENZMG6edQW4HmbroWSN8xgalWKFok71DBJ0/2jtnxwe7Jy82jCgP34dHBi72dyg7b@pqWsHEdnMy6sicH@yBdwsVyvih@AB7y5jHElClA2nz2Nat8dXhUOT5mB0ds7@nh/h5gA/RHm89O9irHKbb3bHv/@Q4trgMG9uzghO3vPd07AbCTgxSlGkSTxvHYwS57WjnafgKvm1t7@3snX1OKu3snzzAxXLTfZIebRyd728/3N4/Y4fOjw4PjCsOCSTt7x9v7m3tPKzsapA9pssqLyrMTdvxkc39/qqAHL59VjhjtAYiUcqsCudzcgqEqpkTl3Nk7qmyfYIHGrm0gHmRwP8WODyvbe@iofFWB4mwefZ0SSI8r33kOQBDIdjafbn4OhZOUO6gC9bL9/KjyFDMNlDh@vnV8snfy/KTCPj842CFaH1eOXuxtV46LTNo/OCaCPT@upBjeV0RJAw6gFoSDe@v58R7Rbe/ZCfQZzw9xO0MCKvklEAZyuQlRd4jAuMsBSwtEOjj6GrEiHagCUuzlkwr4HyFNiVqbSAXcMLF9EgWDBIGIJ9FismeVz/f3Pq88265g8AGiebl3XElAhe0dI8Ae7rf4GlgHEn1OpcZ6gnxxJzCrFHBuiqqT7e2yzZ0Xe5hzAQ0ccLwnuIXItv1E0BzaclqKTJb8f@092XbbxpLP5lfAoC0CEnftpqBE8nLjTBzfiZ1tJIUCSZBCQpEIAVqkbc05Mw/zA/MB8ynzMJ9yP2Smtm40QMhSlkly70nOiQUCvVRXV1dXVVdVh1O0DfiXpgFluPrqTYCpGVctL8W2GJ3g6PHLJ09B4uP8WXb6HnMP7@USH5nfYKPRH@FnJsHMIOjNR91wMpxiqKiuxvaNy3hUxWscXNDOrdPSB27yEDMKVSiXu92vjrqg577qdt3qXWpmwLithhi5P1TKlTFiynZUvNG@8@gRo/0gg6jDNTnGJDc8PF7Akoz8NXZs8y8D12o0BoFUwxh8bFhZiGI@FLnAgxLgjBTKiBcbpF2SAYJ@h0INVNFRzdf7XbSCot8jFZrG8M/kffqD9wbjBTBntmo1GqjDEhjh20B1w51QZgP6RxILhEPqsh4HwQ8jp2l2hyp/fTSdDhzXVXWobAJq4Mhxb6neC0a56rV8fQKWDpUlJ3ys1G6SYPTpsqDMknmpz2hkDv7TTeiPq6Dh1A1oE6WuyBQttklnjaujv1HVkgwVGDxBk4wi34ujb55/jcpcs73Vyb3/RL/ntYXegJhZFva7E6p3Rn8@OeMCsMAopQagJJREF42GUUd5k@jCV1DwAgtR0nzaqi8C2tYBJSDHzv2x2SduxrNwYUIPbPgvXxy9OP7y2TPgnAjt1t727k6npJNkfVPlv99iP5TxlHKERbCNg5hGn4xV8hjkHlopRo7slPyJgBsNLIhZyNWk0UtM16C9MrJ@SsjHcLgx3vIxQQc8O0A82Bbl0bhfUvRauDKFAJzMUF0czaW/IAnfB1GJaEBcVcZLmrUF/oNt6@WvlrgekBCQkBjlmQXKBeWC@J79TDmCkm5DaXawSN1WdMxJ1zQOyNJF3rEYO0u/hLaNWYzZURHXK0071QQg7uehsJTXxIRX9l8pXYjYeSnXF7z5RugNHr@VdHSUnM6Pk6PkFaDxma6J5ujU5iyDPpGWzw49mKK1Nd3TgYXGfFeAorUnVmOd38NYDQTKGboMelau4Y5OB5LvkvxbP6641jumVMzBge10hGLlN1Bu0XCklY5KAyK/VXIJi9vSuUoYa1e6j5Iq8q1OR6HQmUHTL8IHtf874qSg/QNQOKH1FFtGyr47YZJaZVyB9kpICa/UeYJxiJFi03z1bdrMtTkxF3pgckiz4OgZQIHMzlK9@JaSFA6dAgQgkaNdw1y/2uHswgfN6WPblep4HDLpX0aOJXuF2ipW2j2rksxVVQco@MO1XDY0Gd19BhWtj9lHLhGFC7hYb2k9jG1uY6PlqtwdjXUyeuhVTqR5wY6oeXJqytJSi1/SJBm7zEBnOwJR9PrGE7l1y8himWH4cqrldszsluaABW3Q5yECWjhu9MBnV9xstkTOiv6aMthhomzUmXErknRzPXK6HAfYzsMBWUbw@tHkCreLMbdOafbS1iznITmFYCeph2GaIxCZr1sHrNMme6WhJzMl0quG/ssJ55oP2MSlStQ5mYdAaIbG160X/hJhHt9t3Hba@Qai9TDb//MJpR7sJ7xTRtOYNHfoBTX9h3GKEeWGA/tQiiXxv7QVjYZXtXABf6ivmoxcJXEEnYESTBYJ/dc3KgSUXzJ7QmrZpxNtRHrEG5n3UIkv@MRrVz99i09iZ/ZgUAAcvMHjVBGDEGSUm/AIb3W1EXyYG@7rMJgNTLMc7KYDP0ILEInf0wltu8p6JRnk@n4SB0uQQvuNcNGgNrrOp9OLSffxdOyPwmnog66AybUXvADxcUmPmP9zNJtexXQZC30YGIUGy/SZM5hwRi/8rY/GOkaWpzgJIsc8EU9my6MLTkRAxlt0M7M0z6QkqlE@3Zaus7WdViplIxzJ46vldm6su9kqqsyHx9iALKvD3GE9RykmFPpihDd2Vgr0PlTAgLFn1SzfvcEnLAPxPqCITgIyECtgVk7AzUGgdnAjxCeDRXVA6exmmMoneBLgdSaxQ6@rPt4aCZz@IzyUfmS19ppGVTbkLzClHT4sb0Z3e/d3hh4A@AXgtzaLqKWIECih71Dl84lZZpa8lAALOaChW2UVNQFQkqezcASK7TjTaHeRbzX7eXkTNsjJBLZmydi2QpW4Ih0QvvHuLqcLLKe7dK33762KVXEpMwTuiEeJ07yZYIPbPDRp8eM5IhtvkDE9lpYdA@ibUNUHLOGVgTkHThNkzsJ7@4ppt@86azkEekVOTcbdAY6t9kuKcRCZB09WpjNgxnYOe@JtUImTaVS5I/Zu5B2FSb6KcN133VtdTZnYvMVGe31AqPWW@LjslPLw5IgmizFyagIaQhWKnjWZ55G48Lq43rzu8hY83ISz1EVHbyp6vge89nFTfIM@o2qj0UuKYMd8lx39/qQLA@/ezEGkTRbxu8Qxusgyukt@NJrKoUlj6e4YIuoT2HP4GADmsN8B4M6cnxuRmvfHUtkz1adMvkTEJ6b6xrBA4EvREM//MREZH5FoJsVZzYNHmNiVTpNatR7mq8UP3CAGqwS11BbCVsR0snJ0RPnkh04XHVZayIng6dA8ZNdp4jXCKI@7GBjk0L27rLXOOtzSQrcEsiyV@lBLKqIZfp50F9TKCipgiRegQo9ohTdd3H1Uv3QsUA5a4Nr0WXxJm1UcjGttADTwj/mpu0AZOO1KamZWVHYhdIk1wFoANWQ0Dlh7QukvnDHF4wG7LCMQ7fm1g382pAYmgN5pamxjlcVgiUVcQTevNteqHXKVlKD4N6JfliKLuqQuQQMBQwz1vRa0gBkyCXo0TFNyF5PyMoDKHEFFr4XLEl5Sgs3UpbDgOyJVCmxtGyWaRSX2zTZqhY2AYFFcJgUEZJbiImkrsNEVwmKU2C0eT1oCBGJF@4xxmAqZlSwO9cwxAuGRoNUc5aRlVZtCwfRxa9vNfNT0TV/3m8bXZv4r4EdDeFJr5b/uNTNfM92229mqmZqAD9fsNfMRUOGaAGuu8Mv@o@AHM3u2dks0lIyMlCGuwBNUpa5Qb6t/H1sHFParZAzVnhl7rNSvLl/Kkcnv/eFc3pZkiu/88sEq30gFiCSXp8RnKprCYX2QBFYbd3ocFSq6KpWbjoBXKu10aH31@tmzTF7R3lK5ulwGs@1ms4k03DPTqCsvXrRfhNNGtnRjOB@PG9HVp7Oveg1i/Xgb9ziePlIKdAAzAmsirk9nI75KAGGAoli6JpGSqOrPh0MzZz8ekuHcwaxxSQm3t2j/CbXbxVevycBDTcr@eo4DxPGdW3rxXfksZ0or6iQEaqNT6htbHeAAevDFED2B9WEJNYZ8WfnTwLbleofvcAPBqzBosigRrvsudZC1PwnG42nV@no6Gw8wFP3edb7Cs2dmhSYXwUMuCh@dx5TwtGoFb8KxEbiKRUxSx@bUvqQuJlAZxjHL@hfB6OkicuyT72zYVWDIGzjMDcx0XLXske1K2vE7NMt0CGDfqfSlHzl9wlO@MOz0soDTJ4Bos1UtVH0yRVy6YkRwdntpRGoxuHXKBgBDd0kUUFnRaXppJDcU18i1TxetIeKwyW0ITJjU4241MJbp9@OKb5Lh8G5MkRLK88T@5gyRLNK0AmX5AT4xH/M/1WBZP8tlrGD5Bq99WOU7WKGLFUqlh33vxyvn6OjIehBtbFhHR8fwUKtZR8dH1hN8cXxsPYHfx/h7zWtvb3eY5z5x38HLY/Xy2jqGNsjAudG/mD2Bn/DNw8Ak9BfGKX7Q8B5UOw@63sFhJ26cHB1j3Dg8/e3f/uNv//6fjSP58V/445h@nHynC9Xr9caD/rsHa9cd/H3y5KzyoHfyIDqrjDpIZcjuv5zF/tg3HBjr/dItQTqDcdi7KXBHe3CEMXkLoseeA/94Hmhg79/z02mSPs7SR0zLmVb3x9GFT9UtauHQqxxV1tbg6cCr/EuFbCfy3tfv38J7y0VeTnH7hFq8esY6evX4@XMz8zVyfZLehwGmacFbE@XYJJzEIQzqvKzunKudWPW6dVazzjV46GrQ5YJZEFnNZGD@VYBUoyO/EDo/FbUBD0bJ9M0WeT4nuYxHJN8p0znfv@WLpvJw8IgPdaiNDWB4WL7D7tISeonDB3DxFMarnbR2ts9q5XK5pO/k6vaJzVFvEfWl72hSx7h0BsORQBEsGRg73ZHmIS6gQURGuUw3Nq31@WYxZ4KqNWlMrHCXK4Y8j/YmGkhJszm2cHM8P8pYqPDRLVhWPKdAAJQNlnc9UgIAKMLrgBiXxVfuxlHQD4dLfeyOlyKkvcNeiVFb69ZwJWjLsmc9W8Z1f5g2CAhBKYDSxWCj@QYZeVMoGxK34zGq3yBurBLVueSftrZogrVTSjQdL0dj6Mwhd574CrgTYN6VyRpPVDQX9sA1e8EQr3vnFc0TlrqTIty9AE0Rkz4omAO8omiMaaFY4OMjSEqICOsBJRy5omyI0QjOeMJOLNMhPMKGj4FcfB0bkeEGbqlCUKjUonKsrjgTPrAeua4VcUnEKvxOD4CJPMgESfqw3LWWOQqMXKmJbw@E0iK8XQ4VaUlP6cpKsmmt6ANYkCov8YAMD8cAKViyTtdZAWtYWufjybkePx@pxXgjHp2f8YVz1E2bz8iBY@luVMQ2dcfu6DYbV@nyq4mfCHqjaRyHPUBWslTTRFn42H99Bq2eVkrcmVALHtQhgvHVeqRXlDk@RUrBIqIQcYb3Hpp2J4oKMgXxWBHPxPhsuJw5KZ5MJzViub0gCfvsxMe931e8OMJjWvLeJ8Bu7giUBz6oVBNMPZyqBDdyRklTnbZDeEJ/eVz/F1r09glnYuYVFi2xCwCQJg49O6cpktIWNSVQA1mkCIzkgiwYvJchzHEwCpNMnaokAWDPZx7FtUI9LvJzBNjEbg6z6KtPq7Jn7DPngm/lHoCMV30DRrvnSvxtEe2pweCuxncf6po8JArp2lulD82PFDgm1LCCAX24fKvZGaLNFfc6ymOG2SQHWVK10ln4YA/UuIDI/GKdYkyoAeEWeZzUTgAb7Rw2gJ3mlkHKhZuZ5g0CRuI2d3LiUTn08nSxSLDCvBW9KEiRCK5LOqrk3f93v5mp7M0wRBYWH5RCOoA9OnVz0Kkc8k0WrsCrQAnqkp8NWONsjknR2H1CdhTMohLyIjU61XDkulJDlxmukaQUUYoO@HlSMecyV1WNN619lq1dq3BU0TsVW@QYkk7kSsiRfL3Hm3lrZ1u1y0FDdPRGv65VdJMEB2mfCTU7gnLaXv0hoge9MOiaHz0510WkoXR4xeXVmEWyAOEy0zi1RUc0Us70RClAEvsqHM2T6fPk15fpKb2xnPXpl3TjJ8gFPojBIiL4bkOe4BE9YN1fSy1APhACI2AfKj8O4LlUYslDNEz7RTw6ni6cZvXUPrWrrZ191yY9Wcth5X4MmlG5H3DCLrw1UHRPSgxIdu03AbPwWS8cDIKJSgcKVaU3/akrzZ6gOf@dZncxX7JqExMPbIOXxzWYRHohuKbnaOaPLn16/Hz6euYvn8MmRD9fTng@X2F7X8BmhNcC0ZcveI0eDUDUsK9RT05p4k5DpJAlHySffkKiASeDM8SFAgQEKwjgPvX44@xgDTSY42fbhZaead@EST1nCSVmR95zPjg5L/Gds5d4KWqX3wFtOsaltPJIn3I3JYuMgB@Uj5nxlmuwqD/Gk55gkjmHUNlrhfD45mKuVbXGQKBNpXJ9eChT9sk919DH56LYJP2L7uV8nIQyspVhqXFhpfz1u6ROqhuTb7iCl0yGedwZ48B2T0JYpakuQ4wqxYIoYaoVQ39U6Kbxk9kxFRpEVeHME@0too/mdecDc8PS/aFSNTAxhHFgo5RTHGfJUDegdqeU7rOWHvX9jPKBcABSEIz1iO4@JtZ8bc4xzjCmriBmoif3t9DZ/56VXH5Dpw0plpReitGvIDIwD0t1ffJsr1pNOcQ2tFqgFL78enoZiGYr6oShvBoXl3E@x99dYb1Fc8tIfwaqlOewKbvczyy0jHCoXDYNdGohhnZmcxZorKYwYkoSxHIiic1nPEtL1xwYXcg2WCmBkgxzXshWEpMeaQF7gyZWNs@qFiNWPrlKetMSEBUFmhoopiq7W7qxyaXXaNVLdzAFa1amNEV2K91AU5m1QAnXZHArooJVRLV@HqIYriI88ZdfDU1ZBGSxdF0qFZGvZh3immWudR3FssKXCHH3tSCca6NA0O2NMW9dCli@Obw0XiT7fSUMr1tHI2CLWVmYPaz99B1rPaxAxrmoZW2IY6/4@QzzupZBuirB/5hjF7jUJRp0MhYQEFkbJV2IYpQQG4RvbY2QqHmrUXZL4jPUKPNNNa3dlkud3KEnDAL9BeI9s0E8ihmuBGDhhkIix7rVlSC223c/2utuMEtnxldokgaOnBqlmT2vRxE6k99mpW6UJZuCY0Hzlmv9TAM12UravAehnadRLt0DEFjSwLRu0BnV3hADbxzAMHRSSDbnpm5YrB8qQ/cfyf6tcKx8FYQCtIDQVNIBymd0CzFPsEgIFExJC7TyMK4AqnUoR2EvqahG4iKhNkPJagdvyVZdaBDSs0K7dGyll3jOEsOqWGg1VRYiq1xYzXIwyyVaM@joKOijIVxbqWLXsAeL2aEBbcul0AAWB@vpJjPsyhzO2polsJHJOidjFCr6GUQxHBlknE6YOedJF5gQviTEy5YCy0RLfVGh/YELSIl0da4VCyLIXlM5JLXQNFK8zyca88XYoaofwg8FQ0xzQS6EE@KoOv1ICk3ppyI0j89biJQMen8/VPqTZuKupCpXR99Ei7wX77Z4Lzb3nmXcQGsD7j74N@xzrCkFN6b7j7VuBgDf4/2XzBTwDxMoxSskOpAduH2cuHLd9b1Ur6vHSZdv7tbsF/U4cbkbDGA7BmZLkU1V0BMT8kGyDDwrB1sKcv9JG6ZS0rl7YYWgYiIoec1Maqd6mUWKmaH@qsh4wtRQQonvQXPkXkTRhHh0Ne1zbDpsUPh9SJHppNe2WC1ChYgrnuBPCfG7N@RMeUNZyTwCa70r3coYBB4aBMtYxzM/uZOIlR7JscO@vrw@T4dxvWQ9/@ki2V3ksvU7y2XldbJpr6fi2Xo5Atli82e28dvKaamBFtqxNeQ2LlQy4JPKASiGCRqjh3FqzBeuZR65/Xyx70/x5Y@6Maz/4cWXdY3@flaIWU@FmH6hEJMWkFp9NLxRPV2e2AMs2wlpyOsi9nB/02x/sG5Uf9PC/vgycCstJ5Wn1C2@Lug2uZpKDU2o0iHZHws7Ql7La/rclrV9bjmrC5rnO92GN//chv@xt@GGxgUmvLxlpzGm/s@5/0eYe0yhON5r7jW7v9q5r35nm4Rl585bLcu@b7UOP9o9XTxpni72t17@WE7Kh@3G1zP4m5R/LO/slfkRHuDXpvr1pnxYPsBiO9flZcPzPHiUVo6eQSuHn@o2sdTyAP453Fbt7izLhzWPqr8vH@7AQ6vdBkhOF0/3Txd7Tfzf7vyRxA/zdEULHze1GlFeFdkQ@CxQXORJLZ/GaZOPjd3hOZKAUsezBlLc@aHRGgGMzjOL9l5TZBUgIM7/8CaQK6AuA7y6S5unKIdJQnk0OOJC5X8QXz2uBCtAd@HCH@qCdnsRvdKcEyrdBEoJKdDW@cP6Dh5dn0saCg2ATjxBYia7coN64VDHmGIL/x42P7J1YopHtuStsE2PfznblF1xT3bF/y1b0TK5mE7aBYnVy9ZjmK4ksL6PGZZ4EkZRkLDEPwomAWzJaEwPpyjo4E1vfbwXbxz@wO5/j1TjVp8a6n4fdzk2hxuqR0vLfvAxrKzwkrSit7Aq1TOej@1sqV/AuPHOMIyTUdE1ozC5mPcoJ/7r2fJ58pIyUTQwr3bCWSkaIMv1Gpc@Og5QJvkYSAxKADuYzScNulsMBDaMlcH075f@DwAa3mcKQxt0oRga@39w6PLQOIgoxGUxHNp0U08wHrwKIn/mc9Y09Jqf@6PgOSaGgcmIL2xUnsrW5xRck5jZcbWyRBgHOVyuZKpxBivi/XFFhX8Sai0Lw43pxhgb49SFCRHvtusUNQG1bA4toFuqh9NpkpbnqHFdgX5ma1BOMJgkDg3Bw8F0RMDNcfwbCogNy5IXBEf6UzpNX1BHBM3MCvEmBxxVMJlfEu3om1VPWo/OJG@a1zJuuCaP171Hcqu5bSNCcZrE2Nzawy9z9r2kc8mSpA7Q4wDBmiGBgjwhczotvARNIY6nve8p7w9yJViQSH919U2WPbnRwyMauyfByCdecdULEyowCGMqgDUbo7cguzOKqhlS7c1HcZ3XAgVWhHE8D7Z397YIINrxVdHBtJ8p2m5AyzN/tmwQcBfJ5ViPYj@5sMbBm2As3isENmWU5UVJdIaXavnzMbm17LhEOoDKzEgBC85@ld89efrss6PXT59UQUzZxuIxhSXpso6BXP68Qd@HY8zUwGSEVXj51ns7W0zkTlytfIwWOQb9YxPtGybAqoE4ruMeEEZOxaNq4mfBDVsRqu2TUVUfh19NZz/oxMW43BCUOd12YCvkqpVfLmNIV4x9lZEEM4kNoA4OTEVuz8bAeFYK3cgrAAPC3boJUOQY@SdSrn1wv1bTa@oRPdWAsdZqh2xksR@PQ1A8K1/MJxluW6G141sVYHJ4/M@s7X6F@ELd7lgXHurxnb7X7Oi4vTfO3H2nb0UeIhQOI@719Hip5s@ZS2SaDQhxyctZhUz@z39X3M51mkRn7CQuZv@33noqeXGdmfpTvi7VqcR9mKwEqr2tJ8EieczZJr2koyv0poOlXHv/GLTqgfPW7CNy3HewV29s9D1v030HXc4izEIZATMMXkOLbgffDTPvdIhY4/R0gncgr2Po3jcvPvsEphz9xII4OfnubP1Bo1qpuG4Hh@B7FN/35OWLv6KVf@bWydr/bDa9FLzMfN1JHWb7Mj5pnhH0VRuH1sBVCJxzFCQy@vh4@doffQ7SklPxAQXolkSBcTAp4YEv8WUd9E1CmQvvBzFx5NnZybXddyOPSl3MgmGHbRXXsffGGbmdBP5cmF1sQxdeu02tJ1DJQ6@mHNbDCezWn7x@8ZlXOfAtbNUrWBWVjZ4mDiAUIhgHXx3hjUgZ0gGuQlSVcLQeEQz8t1GxD7NjOWj4h5XO9fWN8HzGOV1B@KmkBDxw5lWhuJm3OqWdWUoFyyjw8AVvbX95@tquQl1MwYIvJ7i9LYlpcRCrp/pgckNOQVvg8hWW8byttTV6h1Xmsee1m00XM6JcQ2sxXmEOzfLCmnWuZ743cDQi/SgsuLCnXW83OJAlbrR22s3t3Y@mM9giPLwTfS0GFuKh1vImTJZrIBsGnrr8Zw3kZNhNvftb63svw@N//mb/1c4Tp9/7tGVX7e9jctufRSYAM/@qzmIR8NiZ5HslIDByse83Iv@HaWNr0OyD5NnaHQS728Fec3Ovvx1s7vf29/f7w6293mB/19/d7vcamG@cqtQvwwlISTaTP3Y7vFu3Nwlme@3m/nDYau3sDrb3h/vt5ubmVm9ve9Dc2hrutfzNzZ1Be6@33/uw1JbCUwIGq/gu7h15DvzwZuGutMLbpbb7fw)

I used [this interpreter](http://www.rebol.com/r3/downloads/r3-a111-4-4.tar.gz).

Function [`disarm`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/disarm.html) is not present in REBOL 3, so `value? 'disarm`
can be used to separate REBOL 3 from REBOL 2:

```
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270]
```

See also: [`either`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/either.html) is like if/else, [`prin`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/prin.html) prints without trailing newline, [list of all REBOL 3 functions.](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/r3-funcs.html).

Capital `V` prevents creation of token `val` in Incident. Note: lowercase `v` wouldn't break Grass in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## 273. [Alphabetti spaghetti](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Alphabetti_spaghetti), 12950 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet     /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeeee;eecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];#min=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<66PLers95 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}Vngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrdisps94 Cr ~-<u Uithw;re!-  hardoc""?2:body2FACt$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*  <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPl5m3O7mxySffveAdHoQqFA1CVQha4qkECzeWNmvDGrsRReeTyrGI3WuiN55ZXWjrDWYVtyWApHSK8OhZ/0A1p@2VBsaP7B7DknswoFECDZo1HEPmyRqMqPkye/Tp48@XWyafidX/wigQ87cruj864bsMDyA9by7EvL09j2iD0xbL@QX5YkhNryzgc9ywn8kpRgOmOOdcUOHNNugRsL3AvLsd9ZHvjlGet77rln9FjQMQKw2BCK7Vrd9733ATPdXs9wWj5ALjN2ZIBne2BeMKPpB55hBrbrgNcKYy@drtFrtgwGEJbX96yA0BcYoDAvKMykzypjz13PtzB60/J9Fx3XGNuwev1gVAVLESAMz3afbb34dCrwOmOfGpCyftcaTqVFz7FXtuW1pkLoOvv8dH9/2jXPPlNdh@3fTp@@zF56vtE1pvGvsK1B4B4E0@4FtnVuOQbLa@taftpzlW17xq0ga8yzjFbb7lqa7ZhMZR2r27c8hi6s7XpQZYHVLeaKucbWOKRmYtji2HMKbSV8mOGd@@DpXlpgtKAm@rbVYm3P7THD8a8gJn09N4ZHtOuT5GBCAoHQ2Fc@hG5ZzHfsft8KuCdk1/LIG2JmXdu5kDj1HXlua2DazjnAWVCu/UFAefIlE4JVWV/QsIYGlqBS4GCQhBO3Z8XrwgfihVT7fcu027bJC8caBpbjQ359jdlQd1d2t8taVhcCjLGbGea7bODHnJpdo6OZmoSFi7Gw3kWX2czs9xn3gmxAkvZzRWb13K9s9g78ux2fDfs95ts98A5Mt922LPbO6ncgOOu1pJYrMXjM/lTOItuiBTCOBbnbOfoSyi3A4nTakLQWa8bgIB2UZsqx4bhQfB5zjB6nBrM/otwDmihE23U1dG@5lu8kA3blehesaZkGZhsj863ztjHoQox2G6sD6MD2Wc@FL1SiwyBZEDjAskDcGJk0MyMYTVi9Vh8aJlavi@QCdR3W8pVnAH14vqjHwO4BddhB0meW4dvIsSCIbzktoox@xMtcyG280tmlDQ0PimLgEW7f8oj0CS/DXABKI6JV5cqzA6AIzMUWO7IMj516lpXidGr5ptFHKo1HCZG5GEOAGdGIMDc2knuH@0kgUB5CM/pAkN7y6be/JRlMq7DFRhl@FVkuS3svdtn14hmaOc8EIu57ipFila@Znz07s@A31JvZc@9GAqwSlEqXZd1@kDXUPiRQDSCBWQONaFIv81q/G4uYbUzVQazZcKgW1AYwAfZ5hnJmDjwPufu4UI0LyHTXdc6hPCGz3sDhVb6agyoA@mv5GWZdWkgDvI7cKyrh0w5QCPwDaIyz8A6HChS6HGiKokTDeH23OyA4COkH2B6hVCAoYjxos89Z27C7GAT8ERVPtWf5QJwYZuC0sOZ7tmO1NBYmg7iOB23xEqIzACk5QGvoxXgLJQqAoSJcyip6ffjN32mdnwOeLdN0vZYg18@B2E3qGg1KLHRuDAnWdYwuJQvgMhg7Dw4RXBpdu0VcznBGIgpKBMV65Q66LUYN9cqGJtcxgNlawCDMwOJE7g4CSGOG9YwLzhFtTrmQ8Z7RhIqlCChuyrbKnuxALZnQzIlm1N4gaBeZ2t9jST/7WtksKZsLZxYkLqWllhaz2fMyEJy2RE5gS95FOZ9vTXQVfmD4rt2S@qOg4zp5pppMNitu33KU5ASOZCbpNZMpDTm1kirbFVNr205LSW4ALVYh4mSqbFbMml2ql6eCx6MENFeIBpurpZgpGVkNNYrLbA@ECw042eeqMMX8XL@BRY7eWswZC2ba7ZI7JEh0Qbp0kUCAD2l@17L6Sk7TU8gmEG5mvtFjVk6ncIgMl@x6OplIpuNZJwyQ04mMYmM9tV1kW91@B@UNKBTH7wPP9ZB2TQOox8dOLQCRLsOaRNfUEwJnIZ54ZSWBazeBkYZ0RE2SNzkMryKjFBjGTWiyJVutWEMGJgBtOfBvceOui9IBpQl7HmAdDkZqnEPVQGCekS2eER4TuUxm6cIBhoLYmhYrqk0bGgE2N@DpguZjeQPw5TyHAWy8kcR4T88YYa/GRYNxg8E@zWA9YA/eiJkW8hxgPhbvUDCSAbU/H@Re5rZZTs0XCpNt7FYTC7zslvodYNLvsne2JMx8vDEho2FtELO7hnM@MM6BX7gOBDFM0@oHglFBTvwAWNF0f0OOqug8Nb8jLT6Zjps6kVA8GseBTJ7XnugKDeQuQmxXQSZD0Y@PBVjL9oAtQU8@FTsAXE5FLr9BkIkEvJHnJCGUAIDIrKFlDgLgakDAVx3b7ADNYuoczhd5JzQdPTjFYwfOrrajqDExevVxXtKykRMmYy4KFWv0Nh7oXBFVdcKBKj/ucDdmw@/NQOxGSYSOIOaqZQ0NaO8enD3XcWcghYKM0CLIpA@vB5DETlAoho4rFLuosUaSclRFUGfANaDlA/11gqDvl6CfsIPOoKkBpWRPvdFBcOggsWQDb2QHLjc3u24T2LIP7TMbxpA1B017OJUhcovq8CtfugQBrO2zCvTcbwdAdUqy7QPDJPcdBI55ycS4CQV/ywBIQBoUlNL2iRXvA1M5GTmmIk8QpZxhMrZdOQUGDBgVzbdQeJtM5lfgNJ1KBIsnRssiVNb3TDKoMZkU0SM4JUt6NJG1B6ZReiTL8GobXd@CrzPodtE6cDiXU7iskGLX0qNHwNoUis7u9bu2aQcN7ssePxYyBVuAMR6KTW2UmVIQ5pEYTGvAUABGdD8cWgvcExJ2lRRk5NHNRMSW57kejzfoeO4VIwcEk@KFuuP2kLuzVyRwoQQNw1rbweG96EupKzVmihBRn0rycjKpfeXajnKdXFhYSJaSVegxFxY2wbSBpk00pcG0SSaVTAinoYlCZMiEvjUKgW715E0txDxM1bE5DLG3f2f3FaNWKi3XM0ZNF988flNQztBjALSKH8CTTFUqaEyl5OoVZFRrtidzv4O93onp2X1RCN8yLg1uF6WwTMUAFed6ODAoo/Byd5n0Kh5IFzAYMDuKlzyr5c7qZ9dnrfTZTTKDoVNlo9KETEF8Sk8799wBiCGp2kpJ1eupVG0ZhI9mJZlLLilKUYVhHIxEUp8UU2mDl7aStKA3VM7OklCoonxqZscjfMNMPpWKigrSgQIPyNpKUrsuQvzNVD2VTkLYVDIDQ7dKMgklY2Ih@JRpbEsTBXR4/BkvmJ10WqLmDaNS/N3qTsENB72TwY8G794h7@I4mhGFdQcGl/L6AiB74ISwGnpODVpDr2abIR@diONTt81HRTv42nu2L1lDqq1PD/f3jisUTcfwL0CmUM8RNguyMpSK19KAG3QHLUuaBQNsA0zmOCU4d4CRn5smU11GYKrJExHrLkw2BxvwGhI8XaZ2e5NZ8DuQ3p2JPBAScqeQd8kvZpgkDj4zTVGU@8Cxd06eTUyR9S5AnmCm30XhW/V4BsCaXeKOLfpEY4wSO6AxmgMCJtAWyJetaC7AcR0VeWE4nHPjEfEJEYAgN5S2UJKwJ2AQcdsewpA4gfMpQvRHiRWl/x3XgcGppb0ibigzYOQ4W2VpM@X/Iy5IaaY/bp0g6YOx3zVM4PeT6M5kdgYIgQNls7N9UuVbiKcHBzSOvy@PIEqZhoPl17JpnDqw/Q4WL4wlsBfw2lCqOEjFyR0qtQNmgpR7DiVtDe2Aj1qhhZ9gkKeGr6RwnLTFxxlIZSgjY6LCmTsSYF0TRvgWyMroy6dL2J5zaXuug4Ws7QFqYEVlrIMp5LOKF8hoa@sgvzu/fGchhxK75azHyjaOdbpwTR9al@N23XOXLQEAkqamccI@cHCGE0Y5gdGHFmW/owLaOndhqD9Jg5YVzZmuLkfjTQMhswSvfQW9AJud6THAnDyfHHxnD8QQvZDLQfpDW46eKJMxLNN5REeTjQHEKkAX6QZr8jtWvzPyJsjJd8W8SUCTh9Qw@UyWASIkpEq08HcUNN7IuQu089CrFZpm5X2PxgQ4eRcfV0/kfkJa4c0GcpiYckbXsCgmkN6q8HH9IuM6y07wrWiqQG333MDIfq4Bi8aXhBKyajPZzyYXkllVxbdMXixfZdmWdZlFLjXGPNyzzJm4h5ZlZtEXOzcWGmYWT@g5p2jO4HHoBdnk37AMopDT@T9Pp5GxU@qiuHmioZM/7QwsyTI7LpPPYIgRz5kMHUQHxsoqlDwIgDguiYKJFSEpcAcwrGtZXbtnBwc0Z991cOyiEfPWkGsJ3x3gN2MER7YFAjmfcBh3MjivPu6jnHMOfwycnLDCEF/jRepZrezSGNtz1/VgXOkzneYU8lHR94RH1vX7LS0YAgIeao/6dz/s518c7u41jrZOn1ayA9/Ldu0m8IiW1ejBYLYLzWHOg2nDGcI9oB3bcXs25ChE@e6ie@y6ARcecOHgYU8CA4Y4nu02nh1sH28dfykSRz263Rt0DUxjaXEKIMJxQjB3ojHdpguyhTOYiwmEi8Ptw2chlm@9fHaw1djdOzo8jaH5atC1DX2Y7V@cz8vQtxCE6VqOF/1htzW5okPD1IlZBMFscMxVZjA2ZaoKbxXdeKQ4KtPQA0Vk7B5VFWeBDZzn9lhez62vt5pGsWittsyVlbW20W61VvJ6sdAuFvKFHLzWVtct9p7AVdUa0swNmPisCE4gYRyQePro2koo4cBQ1ASJZTQzXZHvHYkzCwVrbWXdWDfX19eN/Fpr2cgX1yxrda29kstZq3qu3SzqxeU7ExdLBopWY1uPZoCg1eFkAXkC81PgM9EceOJB1rtirXw@v2oW2uvL@VYht9JqrucKxVZTXzOa61auvbKs5/WWmddLYVicUQUu0YEKQ6nSAdE09FJ18ExJYWcar2JaZQyXoQXDWVxGFtMPl5Fx4CA8VtBjIBaRcWpWuBfQPVxCxika4b6K7j1cQB5LsmSNHAVgkQBxHVnzmqHjOjpGK8gTa6vAKgX/nOU/P5DAfK3nbhD5Fa5Bx/J3revkfhm02xPOeXK@ULEr646dl8mZr0BPrv2KzN7ymgkc4VshfHzleia@W14zgSN8BY4PV7xno5vymQUaIVslZLhCPhPXlMcMwAjTGmGKr6qP/YrkN29JXcQ103tuoAj3OuHmq@WNr/hqRUMsliM18wZyCpLYMxfk52c2ztu3J1qMFI3AzyQ5nEaYnEga@@THyyRMvZy9viPHEXFmYDsXLg2cI1Mjp@kFxBKh6F10b4dsw1CDXhOgtxJ124f3X71mm14zALDTnZ6ZIw@a9hRdP3S1RvaYPjgBOisFk1O5E9E3rfYARkHZpu2g@R4wdb1IkO1m054HCiWBmw/C7wywEjsewEg0r61oejjsxaUT4Nl8Hvb04JAAmwYN4ibn/9lE4QcDL4BQ4vtfv9uCSrhdRR1jRGPByNBwrCuij/bcGhNB0UKv2bU77vWpYMh0H0rTwCVXoxsZZqOm2lfVjuH1cMglqhsIFF9ACXfQGk85n4sJv7MjKTEq5Ml1BubYPWbOgCbYqSURHhkNsruu0aJi4ENh26JAHlY2rwZryAeFMYEHep55Ec1YuWDjrQJBZxAM@Bt3B9xXjXYff3c1UQGZKxhN3QIR2Wja1h2V7hkXg5argqRHWcaErc6AHeeeJuvUdte44MYGGmdnn2fQs8/PQZ4Q33lgVx0Y29CgNHtFn/vowncGfl9tQmUF0HDIRk2hd0cMXpe/54HYYv9cZJhfanaXXg@o9Ii4iFxApKOCxi1NaqzQ7Kli7hrNEQ7VOx9PZRghCTjAcypmOp1bxm4vWvuNb0WaHx77Sgq/vj47NN9MxYtk1vAqyzdRqXwCmfIstlXdU7HQcdk9o6vmWzHjXI4eTh2PTTNAad5GNbuGD6QViOqwLqH66HUXuWPPZMKwyxub7iD2cXLCLQDzVpMF2xKt2nS7to9NuzuPg04vwI3jxO1s9IpNSduzCrZFMpPfUSPTbL7gmgEu5c4htAdwOb6KiuvUMcrR3HmFZrpX@JsrWnTcS4u/Z3d072am6gEcS@0SSdjmzB6lZd5HqbgdiF6zy/FiZroCszvTfbINhFMc8QHaA@nat7uuz07ofVexnHsQjL9nU3S8BG3DUWk9KG6eHUwkqs80Mcs6p16N7rnbXS2eZw14za38gdfGPkF8H8r9Iu6l6/dzr1A@ch1dfOey/Yusd3Ff3dHShIeL9jHjHT3wLBYmFiXnZxBGErgTZ3bm9nNFCqll@Xh5XgV4ZufKGIXfX6JnmVe6Yc/SH5G8DeIfBlgvgiHwuAz@y8S2cndsrYexp1to1@7LRKxyL7oWdGT0vlWlLJ/TPzKEnss9nFm1uwNrYM3kVYfNryzc337HKOThicqJbCyK2U6cEcK5zgjqnRg/PijV2Iej7U4GY3RtaOT3Sjoz@V0fZPQ@DrmPwHCEhtsBz51Bf6JyJ0ZxzvHdJdfphy3bbU0kEn0@liMV75enJgR536LfnYMrPhjEta3KSi6XE/JNbP56wnLXoGs5CvuVzd8TEZPLOOYxLM6GeDHj7DjGU6lQ9faFr@Kk5sO4U37ejAABr69nHduxghG@51XJLG7bdN3ux1QhMN2WjfIbSKW48HNfVd6SjcRuMDae@/Bx5qTZnjfrwTskMTqF0sOB913UEJ96fVA1q7hkDa30fMp69zxQbCL3vligm6fJJb51ojtf8BQzKrpW1NbubJFcnHWbVtfgn@Hqyl341rXlO/FFIouQk2ltC9fD@ArYeEU1McW3@iMoLLsFg5yO1bPIesfowGh9NfDDz1ygoYu/Gd4arTfOC9e3gVE4@J5YbYuJUoHrwLAsMLxzC8c1XVwVF67zmHM4qz6zcA96xrnFz1XdxT3HUx24dZiPBsfG2ZMeJb7rzIRgfOvH3aQAjenCGvnhdybC5yMT6nPQu3@qbqrdm7RR6b6GrmVnLibcIys6HbfjdKwO3wkU2eY1D6DIgJ@IuysTkP7zjsmIP8V3KcVLtut2uw8pWeSPnFu6bntmmvbwnFYLgn4U3pHRBA/xuXcKEPp6KiDq9Oe1m441gC7LdwO3b6lkmwfaxcki/p7HRcPFnV92FurOGQIokfD7y@K/d2x6brhBv0@fRr878OlFQVU6XjerKvcpmodQhR3wbUecbq1zt2l27PuS1LSMwLEvsuGMELfeObLtx0rBZuouOmtdGwrPG2lIDZW4/wl@DuZVqZhc4t1WZJhdxyW2M/C8EZZE4LrM77pXY/4wuX8imsblqw9omJcCsTI4w5ukAdxZF@4gu2MJRCwkziUwEsJR4FatHAgs@twZpYntnbHWsbzMX/Pkoqn8U6Ji67cfMyUqtj3Q5KAdm7kF9wn6mViMntlZOZ3BuX@b3fEJ@xaIWPiaWdNb53imeaqieaVCD2Q44jOvvPPdLG7fhm8Dam5g3bm6UrhzeYXg9K5quDZ8GvCBOhzMnTbr2n2fv5nazs8UGG4vId@GGs0eNov6aVltvhaCpvskvZ7r4SEiEClU07N8E6fSkSNz@YlzH8c9B86sdtkYOISdmYXbq9Yzqz/q8dQvXljnBm6vfGbjTsvuDKoArNOL1/ch/fbA8O1vD9zAmolvegH7PnTPjXPbfDpR8iGysETFHjz@mSB7dLpd@Fcd26fzG6HhjjknJDJOtkhnDZD3Z43Wpqbro4PRd0@rxAQlsfebqQcs3CMeGXDBAP2NmXHNmol3@zRuHJHprkl4O6CZWfGdSVWzNwHcFf3VoNcf@OIzO3bapxOfou5dkLt/ZQNbVN8CN2YdoxvMnsaOzcyCzCU6ybFxnhT@HbvrnrPvFHMMRDTotFEon0Fw29BdHxkBtAhnBgFT3A9cKMVJD9XjGXsLNGEtM9V27ODuCZ4gMGCMFH4xM7yzwVOI2Wf41p58LAb1dHaJPLtTgoG@fWR28VD8x44EONsFKjyhQ@tojM7Nx@leRGPtCIRh7@JYV/Hx2p2LPiXsUl1nEKi4y/@uPmX1zj6lxIbF1RhpMOXbe89fpuIUQttf75NDLRgIDvzuaGyau/FgivBsB4S1@bx4EjocTexapNLgmDZq3hNmq4@np4jl77qzRjxHI@h9Hjxkgg5k0Nu1TFx5vDfuF@5zEN2gK@sD0@0dW7hlYIqXzA6IwZ65ptGF8mndG80JoZ3RV4wH10bfakL9dsem2bLYLMS7RmDMkZ1o4pBGgJHpXlqxu03L@4pmBGPmeYPayQQ9tYY0DJlPMLwVqoFpcoEbp@Um2sj02o7fd12Hv4kJ5@CjP7@b2UD3QK@Hr7hruH95ovebOUibzO3hJd9uYrX4wb152fWsptvlb8zCHHbg2HxzgeHZlp99ZjuDIbkxFWS32cMcvo03p63hNIffgcZ2ZcMYO9rdi5vV@FZhf2okBSLxpeHTkv/sMc3ETuKH7yrqGJ7p4tqZMHzkylnsSNg9fDzaKs23JjShUobA0AxzEOoVuCep3V6zR6@5Y5JYTR9bTTxy16Tzo4ExnCVETh4dE45Th7dCloYNf5UpRzDqSd3fkU0P2SZL3O7Tixj61UwyCaN7YVvmOyN1Dy@NWhHNJWcNGtHObEiTm@BAzOlaatDBPZbZIJjHMF7YF4PWA9a6wgWUQc/CNevJlZu5ROX6HaIId/YqfcRwPUts3cZdgtD0QzNyXXVrLskievg/3P5WFjrmxuoKnuAfDNVzYGf37wuAxA88R3weQnZHrh@07eFhH9U4ud48/oLZKkAQ@PDmgKaleZmA@nQGXT7fcR7b0dVr0fgOpMG2C6YusfDAUi3nUiUVR8NwudIzQj0yc@twenOofs/u0Cs/Wg8ED7Xv0zfb948Onh2ean1fv2PmEDf8Dewuru5RUkI3yCCZ5k9Rn9BetQcuVqjwwdW4ic/8/RH9jtG0AiNrzB3qoK8VzJb7np4@f5Yen1tmyk7Hc3tWKu69c3KSgZSzb53M9I6H3gcCb7vDucEP9nQ9NYMCXzq0IjiP682IaR6mUwsGrEBPT/kR2ntlJtPtW63TUd/6HDpE5Lz@A6NfnZvJF8alfY4Nia3PLShqa2xdW10JQT6HwTgeibp7VPKZDXIsyOcmfVP3QB@TLLD8Sy/5TwsnLCe2InxcID0XzqIJag1sPFp43iHTHYkTp8BIYVWk2sTPiPOJ4GZ7QgeCr4Xa18RhTuqbw2NF4GiY5gCnEaFaNEaAimKk06mUJEI9da9YD1U7YSCfziRf2P0yy4VGTGUHxC@CR60MCls02EaF5fM5lkqVuYITaKvAgAZWmbXtEPWW79vnDiQhTAHppkK9NVztlc9gjBeEeGs1tng9LOVK@g2rMLkks3qdpxgfimRv2CfFUsc8eG3RqFcWk6qaXEyeOSWWS0bgVte3ZoMbE7CQWPyIBEfly5XOuaQxLirNMtfLAzIH6rzqGE4LKFK0YMi/x7XLcNVFp7hX/S//sCVUgZHKu57tG10oENTmB8yk415t8njD4ur3DVQlhjiuOrgOgbGrO1vMv8I1Ba4BDKrr5f5pUegVEqoDwXLEZ5qjVHDKweVuPCMdcMLgqYnOu4qIo1BhpmDwPeg5IO22go6vsRObjj8PvPGBJqFQ0Qk8XNNqZdgBa1m4LZhOtdMSbtd1L@ikG6bkL/@Qa1Ois@3izHEYPWlRi8WIR9h1UmFkmu4AUh0ieWd5rgBRsJANMxjghglS4kfuKTzxTWqegNrVUMkRRcM1He1snTB1jyVRPSAqJSnbbWVx6/jTz2u5euVr1sta//W72dS1KDj5E3V91ZczLAQp3yBhxb0L4D32TTJ5cSjzCKOD/7Zgble8PlC1IScyPPsf0pjr9sNmg@M10ssWUaPQd6Kgmeo51HbUIx13RLDWFWk7ohOmDgoQpGPRhwYG1hSh5q2usqgM@Bq@ehKwAkSIGqMMMHGteHQUHjX3YJDFIXvPqJMH9qYXcmDjBdlFZVG9ynZ4aGQ5fpgnu2s1B7Sh/TKv5QsVys5io7JRJRMIhC4qbau9Phvmc@rZcG2vDkNQUahnZ8NPcvkvoNRdD0I9zmLL23uxe72oVXPv3/vGiMnyTbLMDx8Bm1i8Pjo42js53Tp9eQK1cBOytn1@BDHkNUhFdKq443ZJHR6UC44FP4L/RLYxG0SFq6mUFD//SaCirGVVXuTGGGuaCH1P8FnhfSvmfxtA8LS2zaSoZwAqMIjYsNQw84M@KvVjIqxQTEZUZmP/gQ0oKhg84jWDl1JRyawChaVCYT2wqNj8zG5yt4eU2L1Y7i62zZkgWGJRfLXIn2dxZhHc/Ery3Td8/@@fb47l7nwTzB35BtDINQyzv3Xw7OXx3mSwsJMnrltZL4iDz5w5Y0vj48lQExvpGxEBcQ9ERWYyBeBW0ZlxfbBWcGVBtgRzNHs8MFEopV@WxoQJJVNBlcR1IYUoCqUA5RsURKbPZcNgL5bEsI@OobvmWYyYwL4coQ4TrskCc4JU62r4hNlArKK4wqZ3RExc8OukHxd/MmGLw6xhHz3weZub01VFvY7P4D/WK4WmfJ0NmejO9DpTWR5@Xcs5hwyHsKky76PYIi8IeZGnXY7SiypRIU2trwxadqTzRuI8M/TSXaPvh8Jggr1wA6vE3g5c0pkSMpNIviBtvAbXYExVy/Xyki4WGPGA6Bv2W4TvYP@kgtIZF82Iv8dpbuBgRwVAXJmw0GoQeKh0mx8351o9eZG7QoFk2FXS1J0vFMZFUoLPLm3fhuEPVUIbZZwucErMjcg4KqQmbTkgxfsgk7Sg@wYJJcCuFoQTjQ7B8pOwqsPkBNCkFomMGSZLCOtXbisUhK70Csdjb3jgRYIjzH4MZ3JjQVWh5M5tJ9Q@XUJ11DRrVWKBN8A9rtXkrSBhEkpkUjtBrxsDnKFa9czKfvjN3@HqVM8CMP9QmIe5bbD9urC1wfwboY@ug@2fRbY82H7Eba@zWGW3dUiO0xmpA5l7bBiI84l8K2PIGEI93JShqMqxuj8/OGK@ieqdsUJ7MKoe1xWymXCcwuweUMYlVTSC8xjG9TjGo9RwiArEBUSCMg6KNRSf5dUVVCdYymYx4bgaqdFmY2vINwCRdsG3A9SqC5JYdrWwuqJnIZHqZYiQFB6d49lHjjCVKgFjlC7tfuVN02QbGxtM9k2ja1VWy5xAsovG62X5TZTQRYCV@GihxiAMBBmHAL@qCKYsGmk9hUGxN0vqSWRsLZfTG4iEChkAJIXOTqgiBWROVxQVELNjDQMSm0bhKAi4tuPG1GmHiFRAxHGj7tfpNjk@z4hT6LFWqsWrQX6FYDSHVJJnUWztNTsLzpy60AHMgPp@NoN@HTD/kxmKgTlloQqo2xpplWl9spgb9uTEcXElYh9Sy5R8Nr@c1VdTMQqVBSpIL7b394ASWjhwDNOyv3L7/tbO3sG3Do9ObmkmI8jkNFiSJasb6TNVy9TqkSEZpXuyULf3syfPt/fDooynarwWgBDjzd3TyZwV23RK58T@ih8dvR03edyKSM89FDFNJKr7dEjiNvaxbzYGuMNPrt2KVUld39TqG9UzJ3Er@veztE0ntCUkLjCd@aRrOjmdTExidLPEKd4s4WuhXgQdlSLgadnAvRirWBAOMQ8OHmIBDiBp2RBqHvOEBBzyGaCxLqA8v9rCJ9bHZ4lIB3CUohjkaXgJBjatsepKobOxY/idrt2UoANvoR5TrnEpVCkU6WrS/H7XDpSURFMgFRSDgIkp4iqMYWmo0RYGhTROE64Mu0sNZIgvJUEjAHzJo4HfYUduPza3tWuFpmOQRtjugK9vW@xbgx7AtelzbCGLtUA@USEwFFQySiofVUPLElogh2nUtAnx1VAXpMi41msVlGFK61jDln0ODFxJZaClf6KDWBXpqcBMk2ZIJwk8jpfwp3hiMF6kH6UMdDhGbtQMzXZa1lBB7ValOsin6J68enWZTMm3aIA0ku6EOgynVJOGDdEIRIsYq/Wcamzr0f0XU7pj19dRQxiq3IBqgRhPAu8ZGKF/Uto9o8@UAenM9ZnGyKqcKU7GD7wUU6tc7Y7D0mkaVcOHPEBqRtA2mYhwmILzkEq2ArWDrr7Tws87u89quqbVwUyRpNgizqjtQFeOc1EpCUZJEKREaCtYt6yEKeLUq3HKgzDoL5ESP4aKY2d4k6pXmiZ3sSwo16z6OKb8bNwCeamur5dEbUyymnUGZHGby2tZQDuDhYRSKpSv0KAApYZXIeCdGbiABmzhyWeW41hQQEAzPQP6YGMAROalMuHdN5mx6nyKIcGT@FSoZICETqrU30ted3GXxWK2TJMz5RvoU9@cYafaFt3qKPs/ZrVs@VpZ7FZGWRB0UlVlsVPR08tL6fSis6QsOtjVP36Mczo3iyBJNDQYIg0BSF3spspAzyB5VBad8qKxoSy2KvklCgFWGKRdQ4Cv/ax2vWjcZBcfQ0@dARePN15l0SetrDlN028gfdhCFrMZoJlrVGJJF99g9It2Oo1p0BYbmICvs2cnaeLZZydZmj4qC2k0e94TzW2Kq0Y1cevaH16AwllUNDD2PDJ2cRKmEQKPFeovz/KbI3vwiD/DRQRG@5stPy7@y5M@D2csgt8lSWEe14HL1eJCAQ4VKES0ZoxUCpjJL36R0FeZrCxuri53L9PJQq4ML728xgrsk8Wz/EqCJZ4YRgBD9uzS9dlu8fySWe386ltVrdlt7W396OLo6IvhKHWmJBM7h69lfQVA19g6/R76rLH8nId93JNILGWlRHZJf7yWzb558wZEXnxqVa0agmj1VE1N1mvKmnDoVdfWljKrxaXM8ZNkA9IC2U0p@XzqhNl2lp3Zfb/Vgp/boWuolAR/2OYmxgcG@GfCrTdsk3G4ZZ2fD/aMEXe3EwP87Aci7PPvvHr1Cg2v6GHvjkX4BMco0CVKDaOQoETmc/m//NOFm8z1UWPjL7/Xy1oL@DnEzw9vnqP5RC98srDwyfb2ykoGCo6bj75z9OXW1tbKbqZwVCtsrqi5hY2/@POFhXx@I59dqPu@Xk/WLr6Q87kVWfvL3082jo6@7ftYd/gsMx2M@C7CT2eFArtg7@C5aDP8J/O7VsxsoLnZfocdJAjLFWI2yWRhOXnyOon18y6h63piRH8NytoC06uba//tx4dvE0Gims@@8uAbJN4mVosJbgQD2JZD22WimthAsNWbxChbqVTAuPbf/i2Er34L8KDPaANe1UKIa3WUqKoVCvI@UV0Fg57PQ7z/93e/KyWqQ0hEtXqwz/LV/JIgE734WH9MJifogIBxltCLK4dPyGpbTw7zhfwGmh0Lr@@B0SiNeHU9f8ZE5emiCjG7Or65A@uAGevUTbAQdFznLKQo9ipB9AEEQjTCzcKByIY7vJqGe3VmGEtr6ZX8E6f8KvZMWH71zzHekra68OTNbja7UYV@Hp9S6clZQzSyLFsryq77BKf@yuyZcC3ja@iqqgvg8DsjRxUfUXyJYiXT4EUUtrHQh41tLO6UECXJoub0S8Dt4fNX//6vfvJXP6a/n9DvP0uJcA@UWrusV8MH6EeuevL1mbA6z9lz/jgO/MMvtKILOoDJETOTieipVvFF/8JGJvpOuQmfamQhiHGQuXAs5FcUr5T4Optl2ALYZZiZJwulhWJptZTPNsLsUTZ4ysnwPJa7cf5EfjbhWYA/@ocnsuJ7gVyEM4HcfhZY9SHPzA5AStQStXqdt@lqvILufo41JDpN2BrxLuVSSqjApdLpYyBSJmgbnrP0Pc9L@GlaQ9iy2hhrQkr8yp@qxBLX8NTT6s1NTXudLpfFP0h35ciGDzdB0uo3qrrxuppO1yiJtapIa3LFTa66TzZUVq/yDNBba7zeAPTpjdpGxd2hn0Y0otZfV2sbkzjg2VDr1SdP0li0TwBBdbHOYFwBtXGzcVO9qW3c3GxswP8GvW/EF1xvNm7902f8zIEZ@9ex/s9q2epZVjTKah3sWraKLlr2DAxV@AJcrVaTEtdIOqxWJ9WCFbWmrxbqKqMWsgTcK1vSl/LL2cLwk9W9PDABH8HzspxdQsN77CxB3FmXEjhwWOfjh3VyePPhm/8Tf2cfvvnXYIW04R2O5Nt8i3/P3uHf2wD/Tk38O36Lf@z0Hf4dB/j3vIl/Rz7@nb7Fv60m/p328E9KVBgDEW5xM9fNXeb0C/0CDDbLgQTdyXX0FvQ@LGex3Cg3Yrmeq7fAZMFfDkx2rs1y5yzn5BxdB08wBCwXoKkNn3P4awMWD/7sXA6R5y4ZxNLFPo20dNP3fYOlzqQaS76xQO7SdC2nrdqNemG1/7aWrJcT2bOzLBdGWX6lTFrZb24YazT2Xuw2GllsEGfP3cPx/@FhL26987936D4/dHsu/B8eHj4/A55WTT9Jq0/gqVTTG@KzmaiWN89KKhJzSNaJ7MbmWXVZRfNqGig1j27pj3zGGOFbXTiTYLD@6tVVmTre8tVl@apMhsjKDQ0BIMC4AUKVRYcNLhDu7FWWOtkreC4JL9nQeAWeoYkbsq@uzlCkhAFE9A/FEbf@Cv7t/2/9P3/JlFo9BY3g@mZDoSeFf6nU9c31jXhXU4oiLMoG/KED2DHI9U0VjQR0Daaakqqnbm64G7yV1AZHWMU4NqoUeAwIzCMRxUnx8pfyq/1i3Pw5S4LkBENrRawLnp0Nc7lUuQku0eKA8Z6WmFJl2nyz2MRlQRhO6imCKKyUy/oSN@dX8uXyirCsFcvlojAvKsr67aea29RXQTxYWUmlyuWcgIWBYzk0AgrLN8wyNvJyIoWJ5S1fyeH0JN3HkpRL8uPHirjBZ7PfTz1@rK/n3r@PnBqNlu01Gui@/P693JBxn05lvQD2XPH9e2A6yZTrKS9cvkKsqDr7JF@lGNZdD3K1Bt5Mz@bHcXYM3wgCT3ln9zMy7sL15RTpUM/lXO8s@fMffe97Z8kK7twg1xUdEWAsrLCxsbpSra6ugHm1CBmXF/lWIOU8va6nbhazMs8ukxeTCeGlF9dS5HqTRH@W2GCbVWioPj7s@iZB9cdWCimlObJS1@ASuunr69yRrawqxfS6@KsspFh1iYk/6LmW0ytLa0tP6iDy3H6QqZavjUoym03eVK6NEk5j3ZRNcVcHno8zHj9eXofCLObKZ1Kjsbt1utXAaz5xkR46RIaOxKElXIDte8kazTkW1us1zFj9LJkslZ9QtevFAkskywJOTQK3Z8V1yn/C9yW7jQdlh4R16reU6DN9bRl6WuhopT7tl1rLsRYuOXvMbbcXwBHqjjVxd4Bvdbvh/SZXrtdtXdkta0FKHD3b2tk7zeRBaknk97d2MvmTl9sJHa2FsR29WWIZHY73tnYPX0KIo2d7Wyd7nx58vvfyCNx96SvvnWFZhjWwrMbVYHD1ln1l2w0bSq87sG3bNT1IRcOyrD6ARU/ZskzbN776yvD69DDOrT/87AcffvY/ffi9H334vR98@L2f/Pybn/wAfn8Ivx/x74/@zXoB3z//5p/9wYff/T1w/M/w@0/w@9Off/Pb3@U/sv8Z/P5LzO3PxC8Gx38S4Pr1n3/z49//@Te/8VP4/Qvx@@nt32/@6ezfT74//4fhfvwHd8P86N/C7484rhD2R7/L3fB7C/53Odxv/PTDb/07/v8X4g@Nv/fht/4MX8LyT3/6F//lw/f@Qz5f/It/9eEHP/rw/R9/@P73Pnz/hx@@/4/zH377X@m5@OsPPvzkj//7n/zRf/@T/4X@/5Def/SQ/w8//ad//X/99X/86z8Rvz@F378D05/@9X8A0v3bP/4Z/v/4j//2P/0M//@Pf/m3f/y//u2v/@9k@B1u@H/@xb/h77/53g/@5vv//G@@982c9w/ufH/zAPdv/gFcHp7Oh@B5SL4@1uWbXyo9f5/SGMcCNECXj7A8CLXbI4tmND4ZlqRPWKK6hA/w6FoxX0wvgTy6tL4OjLpO7hsIwiRopz/5Jx9@@9eA/H8LkIHtfwYb/HMLeP2QLOyLLyY8WZpmSdT0F1@gpxhXfhGH@iE4vM@CdJ578h4gviBv/rAIDOL93wgM4JgAC@EmE0AwuAmUu//8m3/@@@QRhUXnX5tAmQud49CLCP4@zOoPsd2PcxOH/iGyjg8/@@6H3//HH372Ox9@9uvYV6gr65mtDHT1d08DA2DhAXAIuPoQOADUcVzJFtiClAfDwgZOXUp6@s0bSP0CmGAItiQVlsEm6VUy62iGgGmwEZLhMI1v@JdW1hlawGVIrvBlafDaTuOl9GlpWAE/AsXb7Bkaq0VwGuL8QwXwYiAeJtMowuCGDbcJC4SspI9ZY6ky5AHT6FAlDEg2Ejody3peThcruxBhZbjLEBciT0tv4PumUi1WhlVE9zUlAXCktyFKgKpg6obVr8FeIZwALw13v4akFCvpdLUILhXMZJpiyzQoTr1AmaO8pxnlG90Zw82Ym0@gych6UebzI1CUTEDjOz2GRkAAB/@z9JLIDv2HRvotYXiopyGVD3fj/pvoTOEFAOBVVdzDBz9VxdQ8Ae8hR5WmaOGT5hig5NIkVYUowYEEmLSUpvpNkwXihzR83LOBrALRYXYWFxfBtFGVl@XGIYwpYfDmXZT8wPBwjZEEyxKTV9dldMYNUXyr5@IRDT6XdpfgrcP/3gJtb6a8lJekxSTObCR50tLskzT/PXmyxD6BvNN37CYxNb3srrgJns2NdFrOQ5RVF2xLlMU0IcKZB/pPS68TEktQ3UNjyfA3fLQKuceaEjm8rkjpsR0nJEUITctomYz4avQlB00YNPIVX22RJEg@DGL66godcqEb31IsRfVjWiiIMem5f77tDmEEkpHljL6Ka1MpMZFzWspjW5X2Sjl4f@mWSpWv9ZU1Cb5kH@Dlc@IaNKCajuVZ2sYGYq9eqzTdhEaQYFelalUsyzNdqp7snQL46SHT8zmNwejlemUtv1JYKeSXV1cLa3l9ZXV9ZbVQXAa@upor5PP6@srKenF97SYqqyfAmjKlpWZho/qPbj3/wz@a9cx2xUeqfsGGGs2w30jVboVvD13EJXr5LCeXaeqLinKxlsvgX355Gd6QzoxeWKsvLHSvVcz2Ge1JvMZNEJBU6VrFbu8RPEx6JLFH4AQPxIGLlExsKzk4LIstBHiHLN9GIOsFIGOohzOgY45O@v@fX92TYNfX17GflFj4zncCVq3CiE492JcSwM06LNyAoNotraPRNbqtgWeR7zljuwefH5wcHL7Qdg9OYIj1Jcsv5zQpcXNz046WzchqscPDQwm7ERg6L@sY/sZkg8GAfJtgvxkaUj/@lPuTj5TPq/lldVlX9WX8v8eQx/@Hw@fhP49vCLWcl/gx3C4emArnJdeRY0obXLFMFS@BdI1WJbormCmp61al5Zp0EKrcrtTqmg/EXW5pTbc10vxgBMPqlu33u8aokmx2XfMiGXraeHsUHoqsLGS9rIabwZV2ajO/ulZawI2K5MKUNgO3Arq9Dh0JrLBeamlh1M@hqUDIfCm/WrjZEIrjqpBwTEAVo7sWqSg5rmPd4A7gktGG/F6bfOdMSc4XivLNk57Vsg12lsPjZdczwVZX5ZsQDiLCEThOjig9vLYF95GXcme51JywOQgL6aNkSRtCRU2VNj7UgNvV8TbLWn0jVF5Tlb7@@ush7TUqHTiB2HSUXymiO5NwxP8YJKfHOjcWVsfGHBpPUdHQC6gR4NEOe4ZnBwKXnbp8j/q2Zc6B2OkYdLnnjuf6/t8DZttwLrjXrs01nkReTw1Uee737KAzB@Jlv4cHQi3vHwzDXq8JCUQC4gDb8PK6rjsLYI29PJqTy@eRgjLcn0QaygD8@ODTp6ex7@ne1s5TaZVtH77YnfoUBFCBPdvbP42sa9w3DFqIUHy59@zZtFV8oPsv09TUAius4f7k0AIdesIIDDnTkGv1cgIKBlprcAOScrHccgab@uPH@sbq6tEzKNL1AltlKyBgL6/lSqXFLIMGUb75HLJY2b4o9XHns2/1l/zq3vDIw4blr69A1tnX6saAvYT6uCp71gIIkEAi0ERleTNfwkaIk0zBovQct0iv6/y8n@1LdOwWr5LEa2MDCdWjtNwrh44yNrsDiw36bK4jfNAJjZ593glYcOWGAFLTMBj8PvaB8Fb8Ce52CHgc5HbLpzsDHPfk2G2WkzRis/n1YqG4vpwvZorrxZWCvlooZPR8Rl8rrq2DtJHTi/pqsbCuZ4or68srIBKBb2F9TUqAlGC3s1mQOnVZhm8J0Dom3n60gddIuVqnKiX49DF7pxgpoIDIPmCyBWFkvIcT@CyeAlmyK3J@BY9oLesMMBrMZIn9/Z3c/r4sb6MFV7d2crLcQkuhmMutbcuyRT47ILblZdnlYYp4SlwOuCWX296R5QFHgLrUZLmDlr1VHBLLso2Wna39fYynjZY8hgewC@7DLd3QsgZgDlqWl2lMLctvI3QAt8UjWqGU7qEF40Sffe6zA36y/GmYnlwOMBxzOI7haZjXrS1ZPuCWrS302aGMF3hSP0PLFj2y7IEFiFCWz8Fwjt2CLDfBiKQoyyaYzJEBbnjTFOrXcqAtyiNeQFhEsjwkaMO8kGHkJ9wxmqdPnxqdoGWd82fk8S80qwPwsYeDvf3mp582z8@b3mhr79Nj9NnZeWq0RwOved4UwZoNeFwIAz4XvdH0A2k8aDSM7kyfz8DHmfJpjBoWpq1hvIU0ieccI@k1dsBnB3xmTMEPOTZ4egDaxGe7B99to0k@4UM@9B02m3IZCTUY9S2cMsc2c@EAL8j0DNNzy2gfVhZYUklmRrXVXL1M7qynsNQ18C30byt0mzGOmkC@vh7VhpVcvTKsrOXFUTJFPhvmC7acWeht6uuF0oKxqedX0sMSKst320mWVPVNRX@89E55AdLH8kpJPtvcVOWaXt/M68XS6trrpYEsp0r43lxeK72DoVUSxk/4StXW6ptrhViQtbW0kc2X1nDPXap8AyUSQNfUHARWo6EoV5ZxkUphirHDByGLsstGlFW73FaGmWGFJ4yNUuVhRS9zTS8sdwtXC1WNDfDiUI7xHNANN3MlXLZQZH29KEP82aySSiFXQj4C3zevwlXV6BMzTBj5o7GSym8d1ourKQ0PJjXcdoNuXmRv4pDjPQnSKzxLSHoEwi2/NKr3S9IpjimxOyARy27ideekF2IoDbmSPManGfW1dUmqiiHVEb/5rSysnz7d0WCUJWyoukzbR8nV9TS8nT2Y8OFqtUKnU@jitKcWbuQ1Q7cdfsJf2xvCEBrF39DjmThdpgl9I9rp0/K12sC1jm@fXpyefqHexNGewPCSJwRPQpVJ5wXqFEBFb3aLGZUqmIwWCNeUSiiC1BUVR6NarTQqPavXD0aQ5zDcZ1wd8xjRgc8zE53QouDXeGpReDQquZsx/ItBj21zIDraGAZrVLahfHNlB9WkWmhdZMPEUKq2UAvcdmX7elBCqfSmbFUsz3M9OYHnQTedysDxjbZ1ZHl4FPHgcJG1mYWH/szOm7M9hNxB6fpGrXrMmUiHYqjVZmrSKWbFolO@HZXINW2mx9W5Gxh7KK9T5bdg8xaZ0tK2U5sr5ZayzRopcMm9ab9pszxbXSnTpSAKYgJ2QCWHJWKkKtXPADHHe1EqQUIESVwAToxoEWrEbpGPkerbN@XzSg2h3@NrQ5XluqrW3telalmqAncpjxJGxR80@fW9uaaez62Wh@Cmr62UO6xZab4elr1KH0aWrNyFahezD/yEgIG7xaGQAM@798qHX/tuakMtVLhbmXC974Ig0dAaleG4gpYrtfzKaia/uoJzFavL8NMz@eU87n/N5HPrmbwO8gTIGRAefmtgX4EfwIC4kddxRkPpKjJjciY3zGl6Rrf0jJJ7Y7fepDIXCsiCVGCpTODuOUA14IDEAyRLVvgaqXR@qau0XGZsqES/wO3KlEkj02F9O9NBNMeW0eXgKZUtLyndRQVhFk8H/b1avVTaG/a/jV6K@nZzNb2WS79LpcrKAktVfOstlTAyRiqC/gJQs5ilYf6gV8stQKah/ak3UNPBor6WL9UGizVVh9zl3p9vyFW5DlV1wyT4iy/9grxVBreQB3IJbSxjjd36KGF3LahWfT1fFiBSX3BkRVbO5PAwi5JMruWTyVSyjDOTC@AuODqx3yR0B8nH@qYMMp5cktfz4D9m5LdSwEflq7qUuJFQ6mYwPk9cSzfXNxvxzX@fsdHISKuh9TFj5@lFiWVpT47WSLAFMqlaleaPtypb58dbZQG9tSMlSrQ/dbyFkJ0JbQRMzS587E6g9Eb1Nf@e4U44iFYi9YQ1VqeFfcvGwRT7HA9nbbIk5MvwerV8frley69BXw48OATN5yHr/rXEy5tvHctupKsseybJMnEfvs@gWEjxXLCvE9Te2c51OGlReo5jaKYYJd6@a/XU1y/s7nVxWeXjcIUlvmbprEbbHxvZrxPQP95QLYRbXT97ky9AvThu6AAj7gBYO3SnhYKcYmzhCa5yyfm1vLxJC1zhBoWNMk7AvmH9k/XXa6@Lr5@/PHx5uM@e5ErFUnFqheXsSSajJ/XkBo7p3i@4OIL72vnWt1mZlRP95PJK8taizFklMayshLtLFL1aVfWNPNsE0mYl6A7a@qqae1/ldFolj9U8@Hz4tZ@uDDeKYM@DOF2Cgi6k89WqvpRPJfofvvnXeMj1eu/zrWcsiSpH/u7Pfz@/9nd//i9pK0Pypoxu@eW1BECiUV9dS1xf96@vb@DhfoVEPcHTtLKWAjPfZqMnqlnhrK/pqYSvJsTE9Voh4b8XOoiUfK4IfjuH3CavQhEn9o7tQl5/soHFrN8qZihoy19PSIni8zfvGQOLWW2dn9t5MmWztwpusQRDV/jHEewGGBbeVKqLWZyHX0focIJwqVqtLuEaGUtW03igO0/KHqq1m3IdCh0fHOAtOfRn@Uv4h/bX3GHJ98EeeltLX/lLmDpWqELdLmWz2Q@/9tv5/Orf/flvnqXeN943vgC@vb6@vqrnE7@AdNxxyjIc1dEEEZ6XREM0GmRzbi3VTFlK4FW2bcbhw7EhjgZRxwDX0IQ26RKFE6qCBhSiAaK4QmBLeFYsQ0I5HSxPlSUpklxJ6PbOzQzhYEuoIhoanHQtPUIv6PJYBVid9GiMChx6qNrJbPjdgdcnEVKhcHo9wx5DEIjhESoDWaAzboJfqnqZZZduB@VJ5nqBSEhhPcv3UR8YsHPpEQR5BlRMd02xvoHnJBHSdoA/awhC6SSPVg3irkPcXR6gQa4K5Z4DZBhPHQ/kgFQuPcJDXyS1Q0/O7A0AKLOU9AgKAPKgCMR2nW2w5RS7ttPp8lh92A1uVETdEUZ4CkvCYIithUcPw8BlhLO5ipCBh2qzmKhh04o7hkg4Dr6CVoHxBAYnG0pCdNDywagAFx24Vyhr7PHjcaoqFbuVYpQjxI/a01Dl2VjX060IAFk4GPukVZIzzEmnsbIfTZIdlHiakgtUp5JhDNTG43BovZEk@H8w0SJFTlUVeZQxA6K@eKswocggMBY7r0MT9b/p@bUUixJvQtpNShSpkYlGmGfDTzTS5mTyJN5Iv0iEOlYlvBM@NhQSdDt9DI9BbzbAW7dQxwBnBuKAHb@PBZnTQRCGjkJBVuwuQbdtDwYVtCQYKqRRlvUUBmtHLpQO2qCYX2G4d7CQwg@FQmhUW2KgChARzwJNgZPuNL/vOqQzhM5f4w5L0uTmS1xDCk/2wLkySPsXj4U2JMZSxFWqIeWTxi@HqzXzeVhce2x6MEIOyybDrHONlOPk15nC1fThFKUToUtRIEowDCUNLONm1@pBkk4si6HeCr@UzZ6DJDJokqKK5zbQVWffhj7D8bPifq/slX1hZ09RQaTqtkG6FQcjEyi82JHOKKENglS@de0Li49wlYmTrT7Lr2ZAesxAyY5/ULAl7Ozx9GoOvDMcCn5r8FnjxmImFnZBGaVuf5f1BaWBNfqea1/y8A6vS8OJlS897yUxLvVHfnhsnc5Rgl2LWC60TH52LYmH16JDlZI4X1@hs98azqz3FZDBwtOWaASJ1boECFWXsI8BpmmGx0CxFUNuH1EHQG0PWhbqdQm8Ep6PrqDGM8WEpicYvMM@Yct5ifTfkcYAccAfcGDVVyaxgx8ExXz4QQsqRuOTE8BXoHX2WuCXQDVHnPwwfEjdaCYdR2PyZgsCHXY6FFeF8WYRWgoxC7YOrrEOsr4AnquQwhkpWVDkNKBNyymZo47CTwfn1C4RLymx25gyDDGIogYsKCpsGz7XoimUslxdXWmkF2jg2Zrlox5fH@8mzPbPbRBh3Wxg9friChYb788SdwOOTSrX441XWW4O6QbJ9ccj/pWkNp5UfjuwPUtJtv0k9oGXwCv75z1SuoDqEHyim32b9FqbCi2r@oLM8vXMdUhmJSQztZi8QSSMIZphZpQxM4As0zQvMu2rVll4XFK7A@RQWVboiCr7vNDS80OT3W9HEG5Ae51De7N7YbpdF0UPmU/AjqPmOQwhR6FV2Pv2EAI51hXb8jxjpJB/CqGRTpURSTdsBL07@YARehN2zTVb2cPaqD4RfBgFh74rWmX1UOWCdH03Uq5QDP2H3H8I/kPuPxxHGkZbG9a55IVON5gdJG7UoBRCIppRCHPD9aGNfQgzyMVM5ygQcjThdgM/s0Khw/LmNqjHSkgYQBOkhlBB/Ye1s7rjW1dL9XT2HGhapoKAGgfUtTqV6VUrMmPpdy@7fdefcHJQwRB0PiLd6GR2BDVwWsE8RhVEhMHLy0Y9NOc9jU/D8H5fZBgwoLgFnigBbAWKnSpHGmDJEwinJo/LmCesJhJTJyFLeAk3kIp40fOCjSOqxxChe5QlSCb4sLDlCC3tggm88vBC2xBWpWtESJVtsp6EkpxqKpyllKmSYqlS1TCZUOwolVamsxL6Q1XUprxi2bwR9R9P/sJHJ78N7WJ26olgeb9QluJNxRqi2k5LNBcqVVatxOoVUpBdMrqWBx3UHhdDRacM0Sxlw9EEjwezwNXNKrHKN1O8fugYiezIpYgURpUKZHFU4c2St4uwSHmBR8F8EWwUEoIIzxkI4MjNDGaJYMN4sGGlwhkHG84JdhVL5JASOeRBOPRwTiLrIhgMkiKFplg9ddRjBwKVDPh03luizlaZ@cYlKuZlX6HeGRg8hXGOeQ5RgaAhlKSRzsz6zNhrsUTHmNYUAiTEWwha/FKYkjTN8HQ1skU8ihdlyKO4TZAB5xVAYMSCy1y3mBIRGQ11Qa6X09QPQNuV0zVJ1nGLGP3l@E/OhI7hT7/tmJuE1Ccdc5mpv38QxzqWbKyBxoQMPbeCDBkHLFukagXEkiuXKTOEZ3DPhrf@Zptdt5ntGbgJA68Hj@4CToXjAVKm@KTvBkbgrqyU@CDIJvp6KcBZ7EIGPgawzx0Xhhpx3YU217XoJFGlpOmeO7ZvZfD2YS6CW7RLgKsVl@JyrzC6viSJqUI@LEXUnIBQdG008OaqRkPxrW47VYoUg6JVQzpMJiUcz4IpFh74kEB62FdcvHo9SN2PExV7imCntnmhHPaFZxIi2WLArEyQ58G3A6IK893xSJA07qFo3AwU0gvfcXvuOYh3qE0TQ0@hPxjjxgQZ/T6lJcMMHKKWYupPqTkoZsZIiaCffXRQ9lleMVJR@PwkgonCyDBvuoyxZL0Z0TXmRseDhfGdfHx6T@LpPbk7vTSqnk4zH2pXuOfHRb2sjDEA4DgZy/cnIyOUV99KzkRSImcUoHiAByexRZucWpjSLQDdEuBaG@gjE9l8UqkjEv75vPK/uwLD4HsPrT4DL/I7GQG/6eFeOoWuFfDDFUQFwA9SyHtuRxeR9u4D4wJYvKxhH2UFkFeJcTmorwkaZh@G0b4craAIxPfQPG5fukX3tKepwj1npMm7zLCL/Pwq2m20rK4xslqKgMzE8IY5PoaRGfGrh2UcGR0xPZcP6hTopFJxZc9Y6ByoNIdkjMxlTNX3LRgOYkfUQzPflMKD@eWH/rdYM07ZVfjsMwj8yWSCtMKTEv/@qD/iei67/JYZwUd5/8NrEg/T3l8gUA5i80NmHG3qLvZ5rERZekCPEMFqk1kmjVZht@X2@rfr8OOK6P6cQuXGAlXCWp7QxD2vxu27ajxGFSFN8vWeh5HkfUT3YJqLkRpHNmZhOx/XhdzCjJseTFOJY@Qud9aY69ziCehG827OnF6lMYOhRiGJ0wU2jatJvkhJOAQ@gC9OIH0OX0R4bgUNTlBh3nCOSlzTwsinZ/RjUotwAWkcsMRKMbxvgZIRg5JCM4Bf30RxmnPjNG/FaU7EGbWAyShjQJI5EaWoBayeu6qga7WDOdwZvXCQDJ@72DY8jmt4OC1xnbSTJTvDkpfJEjDkpJUs7SnAlJOtZGmXDH6ydEKGi2TpMzCM21byfbIUNgsE8MBKhifoLlg42s1kaUdJ3UgBXokRxqslS1GdAswmt1KJQFFgvkFqxCUzxxXZDDwLOjYSKjMMKcbP4DiJJlwy9MvBP9d9z@9oAU@cs1wiYJZm@kSnEesxeDzQbYRaUWe05JLozfcO92nT0PhyAfBPw2AuHobQgxieSE4yI54w9KUVCvhCApFvlmaniOmTN1A8IDkidqBQquTJ@Kn0NJIHWgr51wC4npq82ECED@trEgWvwIelEwPPS@et5ITRUYpwjTU1I1lYqG@Sd2QK63rq1g5e@/EaornrSSC8@DIE4bVEaGM8HWQ4WmzDyPpuf5JIyBe3AtrxMDT7xhslUu9UMOIKomXO8SZnkTNkDPHGn7orO7FwmLQJFoSetVydt7KoXyBejF5jXheTVHnjgyTEeA60cMu8sJBsd4WR4Di7yVBfMa8bCsPyKIlzTbJJCKyhVpCBEfDYo8HrHuoK@bjhaxhyiJMqCiKIhYxi4fzV/Qj53eXyeyhQh4UwFcEswXp2V3pbvL6zl51KeXcc7e0KRM8M203NFI6iGMZFDqODmGR@F63dEvFxCwcX8nmkEfYpaT8stmhMcE@5TY8tOC6UErzLSceLPDhe5OcX1G2JpHuphUKLhjEJPDzjUUrHWbs7rTzjs6oYfWgi2@h@dAV7kxUcrzzERxnwpoqct3I81IlrW@O2TSpn0QVZql5inJHT8mdUzWNHYPe0FBstw4LDYeN49/DFsy@h011bW0uJPno0Th@2WpxUjfpxjpk2LEf9wYxhSz6DKtdx8Rrn3eki2YUzR77FSzizBmEAr5oJyU@08ZTgZTF@PtV2IRyHjZWowHUxbgbGBFdCUcfALtsW5RpAgViBsmQIJKF4C@WdodFaCudkgTrw1rpGg7qvRgM3IzUaohfDqglXuFO/SCxkB75HN3hyhdBXkkQHsNnuIXv1dOuUnT7dY/svdz5jXx6@ZK@2XpziEeajl9vPDnYY/PZenOyx8YwCPnhJBg4ooVx3LdPqNYFl53O5FUaYd9z@iPMdZSfF3U@MHnvqmhauR234Ru9Jh1s0xwqqPNQeDEdH4jJ6SGjPDgJ@wZwJ6Ei4adHxNtz3zwC2CWPaHo55e27LbtsAK@HYt29bfnjwinVtqEHgt@ExygwXkvDCDtoKRJe10T17eFEbwOMiDaAx/PHFgLbPA1gtjYmCi56PLsHTvePnJ2zrxS7bOXyxe3B6cPjihO0fHoP16MuDF59CeR6cnB4fbL9ELwJ8frh7sH@ws0UOPAE5jeEhdbp5764kaAhOpWJe4BI33cgb2eKzzgAGEjy7Muign8@SAwe5j2107XdWK1mW8CoffriQ1gRYdJEes97iUma45kv7CeSXPl1Gs5hjGxQbNJYqtLeyaK7Q7aFacFx46I0YXkpklensuELm8WVHtCmnZVtM3sE9Jzj3zY@YU1sOUUNEC4AbUYUbUCqMdOwnk5kNQlmF2Myui3rReGx8U6CwYNAn4daRskQlJva@IFI8DnDg4HyQXo4cgO7BIS@iDTwOwJYjBw7AVrgDiqIHuBeEFQTEIDgcIHtmq9zhq15/n9Z/2VrksG3QKLYo0sTrjarUYOObvu1ev0u3JPBZHrr8yPBN26YgPsHjLQPdbngDYdMCkgeeKO6Lwr1qACkDs2njUoPYxuYMqGGDL1AD7vsx2oHPlEpKY6e42cdybH79xHnXcPiWpvFWHKI9VkT1IRWxeduO7nWgAxZ9lwgQ71qZTEcUbldIhdZDw0HI7VsxGmLPI90NFG4puy8B27cS8MugAUTqxEjHpJ6KjngiGrctSFnxXaBInLf9Og4P5NwamNZEgPB@yK/sd@9SopAzE@OkcN8hpQ6qCK/SzPA1y7brQRsnttrD4yrIBc2O2w9sXofKZA7Gt3sBNHZsENubSnUiNrrRcypGx3VikTaBiufE2gSifEisRPF8kTxiX2Fbj64Xo310mByj6V5asbWzDC4iXVk4/QKCML8aEXsbuupWyJ/SmHd8TddVFivV3e0z9es3GbwcgbMFfiFYuImQX2/Zw7igedA6H21A9FDuEi0tvGHDHzQxtNhTJ7gltvIQGYwDOzaM6540ypEf3z582x3Poky7k@P79xUeSkXOxDnywO8oY@6WYbUwygyFqTOx1yPGOyGxwOuV0CVDOCN@/QSPnWAtlKFEHOQjdDHt5M0WgoWEuWsO2sBZxN1Voroj/ClWpa0ToSBJjxKvj@xrZbuSrqay450jLFacSsiiMyFmvNpqvP@E@qtb6HbvRgf8@@HoinemjncPH4Vt905sH5U2NT0fF@@WYrgejvbrO9Dyzu2XQgt5z8xHzDvJ29giSo@IM7OYiHbH3h3jm1t1R20P0GDfizMoEdJYbAOHlqhD5aUKD5CKoxkLRCenu3vHx0zm4xMIC3wPhwwtwQYR9wK/@IPvnrUdYnZaJDRFg@VIeApdJrauRec97mjMMwtvDqsQMkhGlEfELCav2SSuJ3oWEiFoNz0xxLDkJlN3HfIgvyYQ36C2WmBeibEYFmVQmpnNBO98bD@@qVuUW4bLxvE9@bRjmvfdeGGWN4ojim/@Mc7xpMjs@nvF5eNSGA8XsKy3A8pwCyRpvDNWYycQcR8ANW2yBu@olrBKcdM8F7ATYdnhDq/cpIT99ycoIiQuhHNZOMbWhXAsksbl48VQzKGdh9gNGLilU3jyHcrgEbJ4ctmIV2hq3Okpk10QCJl4ldOTOFVA8PpNObr9VRn3k5VIII@3tUVKTS1MZR1nZwXu8nygT3Bv8@o0e5iOCrjtnVGpv5qoeC8xEVNY5jMzE3oC5tVCYfk@3NO5CIOrf1/cvA@Z5p9Brw/j@zFKf@TT9D5Q7sGLTOg/JoA7io5vlQ8bzFRAEHVm9CkTeafOKJ4@SAufF4LEoD5gs4MXV03GmmLDqbTNxs57pDh2ArmVh1gTjjLKW82t0r@5OzpkyPfGt/Dx8fHGhkC4R/DmF9HhupiulZgTni2ddLM8zyEwfiyp5@LxMTqNdOeZOTo0xze08sygJy2zxTPQFoeM@LbaTDjFQJHQrKKGF93hpF55elZP1cvxHO4fPNtjS6SZrj0xBSl7cirGchZs564EEOul6QjsNego3id@CX6QhkyIEoqJDuUpVDape9NGJQLCco0uWhDbPgVL1acrve2bhoOKPzIy3RH9GALS5Ove4X5q1oR6rjwRHhLn9x0FQmVkVZMpKLjhPC5imkTBaxPdY/2UhBcNiA2Sd1yLa2T1Ym51XaLcOZkg06ut1zNLZkVm0OcaTs8feFeti3O3c9lmXdb/qjk0R@/eMlZYYct4F9ZjroFTX63g0VaFoVaRIlvPEcGKBG6SNtEzmTGNFCniejIbD7/LCyxFBhorl/AExBSVsqVeSIV4Ui6o9Gqr9YpTyZV7NadexrN6QboSpPW0gg6PofME1sIX5GtBHbvSX8RnWy3nknmD5ghGSdHZD0ZnP7B/xxkusWeb5stpm7H0CDer4RkSzbGulOjKb6RMCeUf6REd4tHxiDhNF@NsS8uGFEDpZ0BY9Yf0HqWkRzlt0A9c8hERqUhC7L39XnoUnjrK0YQBgNTsepicDcIzhlFw3Ye7jvhuaFXn0piORx1TMRQ1DEncTj6TZTwCiAkVR69qdcnXLMPsYCLwcsf3FIxtbPBb32/AmybpcKeG4dHBh1wdjbi@AZ8@LSZgFCSY@3R8Q4Lso11HA3ehKaiAzrvQRneJBEH0wW3c7JqOI1H4DSgAXvCPuEiliRlMIViBnMiP@tHcASqemxzX4yoCnoLklfIIM4u4eXyVMXLa8U1lhNGKYgL3R1dYnLys4BE5UHWy3cpGBJ/i4FQktAwtbD6WJVUpeVXx0x0HU2LB1DBYCBwrikf3lgZOZMHo57kFzWfEdqxuFxLNy@LRuDjQSMdxRfzpKH6/hnHWo8Rzf/WWvzrhr3F/nqgxlAb99xioFAeSE9djuBsmj8Eyt@KqMJJNNKhpUwOJYwxbvgvW1wK3YY@Bq1FVcqqMPDYmPNSYz@sZtc99FibCRAQe@de4v6DvvKj5KJUTsE8m48evJCrIor2xYivJFJVqjt3d5J1T5INkJkNpMsaDY30T2fFGKY5MCnYCAhpO41OzrVbGWNJ6yHGozcjVjSeyJoSJTWU6GfzQ4a2GNaONxEqJ4kxTwQ3pfCHEQ94LMRSEEwmNhS23GgYeicCjGFqEWgij5YcWbzVwyNp0E6/gMcb3@Aob@2TiQrjEbM9HPOVDnnl@GHmygIjpLsizi2mSm@CxD@4oMnVHLzKOezSNcTaTeBGb5I3itPiR6TbOci9EfCLOKEJOcavcIx9R0mMAPSTfeVWInjfSL7JL0qcGiND9rjVkWziKMOg0lTRxHh0Vr/qoH4nUtfiDfr@Li4ok2F3RiWehuyNfwNWUMcbYMpomHeDGHQ6fQZM4Pw6BNHaImK9w/8fYwx@c45XTuG6DapGAteKEih1o0pYz4vMV0GaW8/xUuMUGPl8UhcH8eTwRvOZ468GS9vuGaWkSyGI@SDkSz2qbt28xXY7HQlBDF3RpJUn69sA2L3Y@xeXaNT23rMeK7FKs9ua05ZXxQSkopNAjnwNxtaCvSFJs6dfkS78qIsywZ9jRfw60aV3ixcbSFvQYBOiDcOpb3qXV0iTp2IrWeBEvkjIuPOKxaXfgmXzuBmQrvBAZT/v6Gb7aBRSGX@yf@WqwSUthGQnXpMaLyVDVl3YLCzA8UNJ2cfGX1iPwVD8vDwzUswIolKUUm0wSLS2LtJDs0sN5JigNVEsSW3qIisFxA9uEmqGJKqkLqPgqxzgyfn17LCUQn9k18JCvNisBePplXAJhAsKVorvSIIk18Y9KAxMZC5fQjbBmssD9XGor0NwtzwbuOy5gqhUKFks7VPDp04MTdnK4f/pq63iPgfno@PDzg929Xbb9JS1h4zo4KYdlTw@fAXeJFsv5ovghOMhbJxBSJg9p68WXbO@Lo@O9kxN2eMwOnh89OwBsgP5468Xpwd5Jhh282Hn2cpcW1wEDe3F4yp4dPD84BbDTwwzFGgaTxuHY4T57vne88xSsW9sHzw5Ov6QY9w9OX2BkuGi/xY62jk8Pdl4@2zpmRy@Pjw5P9hhmTNo9ONl5tnXwfG9Xg/ghTrb3@d6LU3bydOvZs6mMHr56sXfMaA9ALJfbe5DKrW0YqmJMlM/dg@O9nVPM0Ni0A4UHCXyWYSdHezsHaNj7Yg@ys3X8ZUYgPdn79ksAAk@2u/V861PInKTcUypQLzsvj/eeY6KhJE5ebp@cHpy@PN1jnx4e7lJZn@wdf36ws3dSZtKzwxMqsJcnexmGV0pR1IADSgv8wbz98uSAyu3gxSn0GS//3/audbuNIzn/Fp6iNZCIGRJ33gUObZAULTqWtZFoywrJBQfAAIQNAljMQAQkM@ckP/ICeYA8Sn7kUfZBkrp1Tw8AivQltnfP@hyLg5m@VldXV1VXf/0nDGfwYJDfAmGglXXIekQExigH7C0Q6dXrd1gq0oEGIK/evngO718jTYladaQCBkwcntrJoEIg4qndTfX18y@@Ovni@deHz/HzKyzm7cmb5x4M2MkbTHCC8RbvgHWg0m@o1zhO0C5@BGbNaM7N03Cqk2NVP/r2BFsuqYED3pwItxDZDl8IzWEulzKWs6Q3RN9AcG07UDqLr96HiOe46HlZ7osxAEeHr46ew4osIFJO8uEbWHV25pCP7G@w0piP8DOFMNMOm5NuozfoDPGsqMnGDo7rqJvHazU8MM/VeeYTN6uIH4UyZLONxrf1Bhi6bxoNL/@QnKlm3JdDvNyfSuVJHxH5HS1vdPA8e8Z030sRan9F9jEpDg/3FzAlU3@FI9uC69BTpVI7lGx4CB8L1i6iiHdFEDYaRSOdZcSrJpIqyQNBv3vCDpTR1cUXWw10g2LgIyUaRvDP4MfkBy8O1guQzuzWKpXQiKVm9D6EuhquhKAN6B9BFuh1qMpiFIY/dN2yXR3a/MXucNh2PU/nobQx2IFd17snezPszmUvzOenxtKuskDLR9ruJhXGbC8LyZSMS3FMPXPxn0ZMfzzdGsZuQKcoVUW@aHFOuiucHQOO8kogKvD0BA0y6nwv69@dvEVrrlzdqM29f2He89zCcEDEo4UF74zyXdCfFxecACYYYWoASXqCdFEqWXl0OIlJfAMJrzARYe/TWn0V0roOJAFFdhL07TpxNR73pnbrQQ5/8br@8uCb42MQndjajZ3N7a1axqBkfZfnv@@wHsJJJZCwEazjoKfRJ2uWHILiQzPFQtZO2J8YuFTChIhdrgeNXiJegwnLSAcqoSDD7kZ478oAI/CcEOngKALSeJzR/Lp0ZgoDuKmuetib62BKKn4AuhLxgMSq9Gc0alP8B8s2019PcdMhYSBhMUKnBc4F64LknnOsI0HJuCGcHUxSdDQfM@qaoQG5uig8Fg/P0i/hbWsUI45UxPlKw045oRGP51uhdNjEgGf2nwgvRBy9BPYFb74TfoPHd4JHR@h0QRTX4zdAxmOTE/3RidNZOn0mJV/s@zBEKyumpj2F3nxPGkVzT9zGBuDDmg3UlAuMGfTVXME1gwcyXyUFuH6e89RH5lQE4cByasKx8hs4d1l3pJSaxgGR3xpdQnFZBqyEqXZj6sjoJO8MHoUmZ4pMv4geVP7vSJMl5e@BxQmlJ9SyMPseREkqlWkF5isRpXejNxSsXYyEmvard0kxt/bAXJmOyS7NlI/PAAlkdGb6xTtCKey4SwiATI6ODXv@moizqwBMp88dT7LjfsigdT1ylawVeqlYKLewdZEntSuv91Dwh6c89jVZFX4FWdXnbLg1adaDyTRnyqunkcPFeRrHo7RKDhAz4YlLrzgodZ6zyjLLtBwQyCRrwWkb5CNQS2/v3J1bVRaiZUr2yw6XJhQUvY/tWewnoZkPFUffpgESGT39lEDrEFAbzWRcfARhrklxlv0Qy3naJmcI3ggb3@AC0efSCVkvKU25TykOBCtJggoTWEAUt14RSEvL6o1pPXkmkUNN678ZMCZ9yF4tnaLI@B3SQvs0fFG9DGbQ5P7Dus0sVlp9M8xjaCJWxm4JyY@337aGwzGojgH2G9qY7828onorTodwEE3GAjcI61lvLB4JrfRDNag2sfVOywwjoFPTol6MhxHaReIP6tJ1iAGgjD4yLWwpF5hX8@i@djr2pmsV5e4lX/aAJoQiSkTcU1vqxx85FRNUED5DomAvMsYFhWRSPbjvYKbfzXD8A679qAIN2mHbAIlaRZIvkAfpZECQjK2Yuz4aRuTRgKFAD4ihRIUdaSYOFdbobWEnCVtyEjBLhBqlnvz0egyT6mAoqChhXKkdmG@rAIOJVKoKkqfB9qxUN6kpywyu2zuNMQL3TG9PK@d8YETKM1Yi/KdadcQnlpvm6R0@iZPffxrh7IE3uJctKig2GHVW3D9dlHPUPgTme9sLx23bJwqaTDsYofuNTJ/hgHhRuw4Fvq8VxFE4AwugVepNS1RGw/1yeDVoHA77Qbc37AVgpyEc@pQlHj7O6BEHrDse3kR0fQ59aFuJ2rPkmeFjGE4Nf5t9yZoFsRXF4ci1wxHi8ax@xSgQ5DnHGD9l1ivi79E81pnJs7GZZMqkj5dSuF3Fq92Zd72yLDPv3GMBIuD25yIl@IhoTOeOrLOltYUEzU8lsNrYVAUVeHcE5KVavAskom2YVIt1YxbCD@xOoGV2Z4vP2tN8m7AEx4ijFB6FeAFN5NLrfIA3qIIU@QwjAp6pyk7Zysq7KFPEE8SH2d3krm7/zq2HBvyC5lfWl3HLMkYgEdfRYEoR2ysCCgptoei/HsloksQgxXpdWIX6qUIb0/lS059nd1GDInxAKRK4vAWuxBnpguGD16@5DRA5jZmHi0pO5TyC5UAVpB675bsZNrwvPJYmP27isucMBdOhlOxajb6LVC2gEl6gORc9azeZIZDvnzHV6kNHbY6A/rKIMuu2B9fRmgsdMOnx@orbWsMxCGNnjnoS6pGL4uEo90Dq3Sk7liKsLaN1y/PujfNlZvNhsVxtE2n9GT7Oapn59swxTZpiFFEGPITmKz0bNp8n4tRv4HzzG7N76HAXzZL4KLOomPFu89zHRfE9BuzqhcZMKWo7go3WzPuzBnS8cbcEkTLZvGqQxGigyGjM@NEqao5MhkoPpxBxn7R9jh5toBzW2wba2eNzJ1Hng@E0dKn@lAKrRHoizjqeyQS5NOpg8AWiwLGGa4SUUTin@Rlt5VUKTQQLxg9cIGrFYSHxQ7EHNxmsOT4iMP@O28BooQpKInjatyMcDEa/IRiB6ItzRyIeGrNC5aLGJU1NSWBVUKpPlaSPk8PPs8aUSlkgBUzxJaQwPVqQTVcP79Uv7QukgxI4N32WQN5yHjvjqTVoDfxjf2pMUQdOqpKcqRmVnggNEg0wF8BK6fZDNldR@@uNmeMxukGmERgQ/NrFP2uSA9G3t8qG2phl2p5hEk/IzbPNU4V9zpIwFP9G8stUZFWXDFcoIOQWQ36/AiUgPCm1HjcFCFnH5rxUQ2WMIKNfwWkJLwndNInnXPIdiSoJNjatFOVlKXbtMgpLCwHFYnmapCGgsyxPkpQCC93Stlgptpf3J0kBCrHmfaY4DIWMSpqGZuSYgPBIrTUS5ayi8mXhYPq4semlPhr@pq@7Zetref4r0Me08KxQmf@6U059TVVbraazpnICPTy71tRHIIVnN9hIhV/2H508saHLTUyoZWSktAyJwx6gKXWDdlvx@0jt0ZlrrWPo8uyD39r8avCNKClw9U8DqSuB6a/98s7qwFTdEEH2J9Q5fZTFZXuQFFYHV3rsFRq6GkfPwA9ok3bYUd@eHh@nQF2bMx1ndB2ON8vlMvJw08aw1yHU6EnqDUvp1KXOpN8vjW6@HH/bLJHox7vp@9HwmTagQxgRmBNRcTju8j0O2AZIiqkLckwVTf1Jp2NfmIAblDh2MGqcUrAOFK0/PRPz8u0p@X@oSFlfL7GD2L9LZSbfTcB6ppSid6EgN0YEv3f05hmQB190MAzbbFRRYSiXdTATLFuev/8RFxC8h4QGi1CIvY9JdLLzIuz3h3n1djjutxEH4NHtfIbjYztDmZPgBiOd3Z1EhDabV@H7Xt86NYxJbFbH4vS6pG@F0PDuCHH/Ouw@n45c5@zPDqwq0OU17OYawkznldN1PMF8f0CxzIfQ7Aelvg5GbovoNJ8YVnqZwMkTtGi9kl9q@qSSeOQSE5rdnxqJury5RYJigK57pApoSHoaXurJHckNcZ3zaaWDNCxzGdImRFR5WA48SPb7ScX3cafzMKFIaP48sL@5QKQtAJqBMv2AngiG/U8FmNbHc3AhrN/gnRuLcgczNDBDJvO05f/lxq3X6@rJaG1N1esH8FAoqPpBXR3hi4MDdQS/D/D3il/d3KyxzD3yPsLLA/3yVh1AGeTgXGtdjY/gJ3zz8VQYBmvjED8p@U/ytScNf2@/FpXO6gd4aB@e/vpv//HXf//PUl1@/Bf@OKAfZ382iYrFYulJ6@OTldsa/j47usg9aZ49GV3kujXkMhT334yjoB9Y0aPFVuaeE1Ltfq9516kpEz3TiyhUE8MlXfjH98EC@/FHfjqPk8dx8oiYqEn2oD@6Cii7ohL2/Vw9t7ICT3t@7l9y5DuR94F5/wHeKw9lOYEmEGnx3h9Vf3N4cmLDjqPUJ@29EyJGDt5zKXg5snF1mdW3BBbOVLGoLgrq0jQPwzwanDDdRDYzuTH/Ko3UvaOYHNq7FrMBN6XJ9c3ueN6Yuo66pN9p1zlffhaIpfK0/Yz30KiMNRB4mL7Gsepy7hW7D83FbS@/cFbZ2rwoZLPZjLkQrdEiMUe1jaguc0GW3kInfAY@hjWCKQN9pwvqfKQFFIjEyGbpuqyVFl/r5g7QtCaLiQ3ubM7S59HfRB3JGDHHHm4GU0AdCw0@uoJMRRM6hYG6weyhe3jQADpet0eCS/ElydEobPU6MxPygDdSJLXDWolH5lZVZ@HEnHLGTUf69biTFAgEQS2AsHqw0PkCmXhDSNsjacd91L9B3VhkqksB/1YbNMAmIGg07M@6fajMpVCq6AakE1Dek8HqD/RROqyBczZD0HpCmdE8YEksL7a7GaIrYtDCHTK8H6qPmFys8PH2L6FRwnxADUfuh@vgURC3P@AAomEHHmHBx1N0vIVFbLiGS6owFBq1aBzr@@VEDqyOPE@NOCVSFX4nm@/EHuSCJHtYLroTmBDejRl5khPf7gmnjfBqPzSkBRvUk5nk0Fwxu2@gVV7jXiXuUwJRMGWR7hID0TBTl/3Bpek/725GeB1h0dFVcjVVjk8AiWWq0cflqTo@C@Cwc5VuHsMdTrknexhFvSYQC7oow0QQiHx4YAylnucyXJlwC24HIoHx1erIzCi7f5qVwumIzudzex@ha3eguSCVEDdIcU8sxL07xDgYisiDX4PhoEAitxnGvRYHUHLtj7UsHuG@OG1TUsPurgiMhwD7aQaYajjX6EKyXUxDnZRDdMLDCjj/r4zqHRDNxM0rIloOjkCDDHOY0TlPiJSUaDiBCkgTRdpI8d9CwUcpxuyH3V6cypMXBAYOO@de3GrS4yS/xAbb1J2jLB6U0DvNRiRcCr11aAYKXv0NBO2OJ4efl/Ge7gyuanzxpMnJXaLzdDuL/GHkkW6O3WqYwUA@nL759AjR4oprHYHIIZRnO82qKhmFT9ZAhUsTWV6s0gEfKkCkxTxNCmdAjeocNUCczk2DRAqXU8VbDIzMba/kJKPmyMvDxSrBgvDW/KJbikxwmzFHej7@f9ebGsrmGM8nw@SDVMgHsEYnAScGR2O@yKUz8CbUirqA44FoHE8QkY4DWWRFQQibHk9Sq1LTjrmqdNdlhAukKY0IHwV@nuXssZzLqvub5L5I5y7k@EjXR32wy7U0nZEn573k6yNezCtbm7pcPrFFW2/061YfLZOTWSZgQo@OkJyW16CD5MGAGLpjyQzO7TLW0Da8lvK6z6JZgHKZKpzKoi0aSWfHBC0hEscq1Cfx8CT@9XV6wpaWvT7zkq5bBb0gADVYVITAK8kTPGL0sfdrmQUoB3ogCDh@LYhCeM5kWPMQC9N5GXUPhlO3nD93zp18ZWvXc8hONnpYthWBZZRthYyWhlc2iu1JqIzk134fsggfN3vtdjjQWKyQVWoznxpS7Bm68z8acRfxDbcOCfHQsWR5VIBBpBdCa3oejYPudUCPXw9Px8HsBBYh@vlqwOP5Bst7DYsR3slEX17zHK23QdVwbtFOTnjiQV2kqKgANJ9WTKoBI/FZ6sISAoQLBOA6Tf@jdGctMtj9Z9@F0Z5p3YRBvWQNJeIg6kveOLnM8IW/13gjbYPfAW@61o3A8kif5q6pFh0BP@gAYest52BVv487PeEgtQ@hoYOF8fjaaM6VV31g0LI2uT7dlSHHQ1@a1keXYtjEravG9aQf96RnC93S/cJM83cfkzmpr6u@4/5jchnO087qB5Z71oNZmtgyJKgSKogRpkux7EdNbuo/uR0TpUFMFYb9qG4Qf5Rva58YG9bu97Wpgagc1oaNNk6xnxnL3IDctUyyzirT68cp4wPbAUTBZqyO6OJpEs239hjjCCNuCAkTM7i/hc3@t2zk8hvabUiopO1SCc9kGZbY@nSqIK/KsoltWbXAKXzz@PA6FMtWzAnLeLVujWMwzd/dYL3HcktpfxapdNS2rbs8Tk20lHKo4zUtcholhlZmexSor7YyYmsSJHJGAozAdJaSbvlU@lKxwUYJpOQ2zyvZWmMyPV0i3qCIhcUzb9SIhU@e1t6MBkRJgafaWqjK6pYsbBLvi169ZAXTbU3rlLbKrpIFNNFZlxjhhg3uJVS4SKjKzyMUt2sZnfjLr0amNAHSVLrNZJaxrxEdEpplz3VzgmhBLhHhHhtFeK6MJYpus4@ggUnD5ouDAdSa/a5WhldVvQtiMa0Lc2B4kLxjq4cNyGjuyLhxxPExhMkYQXWzoF1l4H8EOAYpdY0OnZQHBFTWUsYkovNhSA2it/FGCGSBKmW9jMQMlbJ8TVBlu@JRJQ@oCU/g/gL1nsUgbsV0Fg6/4YJCKseqasgBwvtXP1rr7nBLp/q31CUNEjlxSrN4Xh2N8FDBfV7qUlagLFwFxStP/UwHNflKqrwGoZ@nlM08giawpoGYelAZ5V4TB28UQjcMIie7c5MwLLYPtaP7j@T/1jTWsQrCAUZBKGvtAPUzugKaB1g0BDrIShM09zTKAanN2ZmltSSqGqmLRNoUJ@sVvCJL9VKHkBkVWqUjldygOo4tr@JSr6n2EKns0mzKRYhR9GbQ1lHYQke48VJFnuUPFrdDCcqWG7mhWXxQ0hSZEld2d1ZWlLSNXNZzOsZSQz9FKG5HihjnAzlvMce6IITwJRFelhSYJkbrGy31P3ACSZHMzpXligiK10QPSTw0pYTuk4Gh/HLqUNZP0YcOQwznzhsRTUiiGuyXpDWZn0rQeXrew6Tk0Pvb4dKfNBIPZVW5t/suXuS1eLvCa7G99syiEnobcPXBv70Wn/Olg6XJ@qNW7cPXj3j9JTcF/MMMSucVYgMiANI@ij25a/xRYtcVo7jB16Yb8Yt2nITctduwHIOwpQNNebATY4pBUhaddYAtAQz8pAVTG@lcvYhCMDGxKfOWmeRO7DJFhpll/mpUAqJUR45xP4LiKLyITnLi1tWwxbgAsEDh9w6hApBdW2GzCA0izniGP@VM5aMOwxR2ZCZzD9RqQ6qVPkh7qBOsYx2Mg/hBKlayJccB@2qAIFGgZc3zYVTMqJOfrpI9RC9bfbBell0ln/Zqop6tZkegW6z/zDJ@Wz0tcdBCOY5puYMTlRz4ZHIAiWGA@hhhnDjzRWrZW24/X@37h/ryR10YVv/w6suqIX8rrcSsJkpMa6kSkySQXC10vFE@k57EA0zbAVnIq6L2cH3DdH0wb3R9w6X18U3sKkknmYdULb5eUm18M5QchlGlQvI/Lq0IZS3P6UtH5valchcnNI93sgyv/2MZ/vtehkuGFog2es9KYw39P8b@72HsEb@yv1PeKTd@tX1f886xGcuZ229VynmsKvufbZ9Pj8rn092NV3/Jxtn9auntGP7G2b9kt3ay/AgP8Gtd/3qf3c/uYbKt2@ys5Ps@PEop9WMoZf9LUyammu3BP/ubutytWXa/4FP2H7P7W/BQqVahJefT57vn050y/u/U/kjqh727YpSPu0odEaaNLAi8Fygh8mSWD6OkyENrdThBFtDmeNpBiis/FFqgBmPwzLS6UxZdBRiIwR/eh3L/lobNEP2R8GNiQjThExca9kFi9TgTzABThQd/qApa7UX1SgAnNNYEaglJo9Xl0@IWbl1fCgaFaYDBmyA1k0O5wbxwqWKEN8O/@@XPHINH8cxJgWCk9zZlVdyRVfF/s2o0i6@Gg@oSVPusOoThikP1fcRtiQa90SiMWePvhoNwTFAm0B1UdPCavRZeStjv/cDhf8904apFBTW@jxp8NocLKo5mynnyOcys3jVZRR9gVupn3B/b2tC/QHDjhW14Tkafrun24qtJky4kOB3PTuJXhERRQlDzmFEpSqDLNUvXAQYOEIx/BCwGKUAcjCeDEl3sBgobnpVB7P3r4AdoGl4mC11rNyAZOvt/cOnm1igc0RGXaafj0DVJYb/9JhwF44AR6zBqfhJ0wxNE4oHBiK4cNJ6y6ms6XBPb0MTGWCKKgx4u92EVGD2MZH@U08c/ibRK4XFjuq7HwXPqIoRIdjtFOjUBuRw@WkBXhHeGwzhJz6fGTQb6mc5BeGwwSHw0BDcHkx6BNMf@r@lGrCklL6gdyU@pNHlBFVFrxqqH12hgr8LB5Jp4x1xre1Z5diGYdX7Ful6cIl53nsmV8o6DBMVhEmdzZQe/TDj2kvYlMwIdYPoBijW3BBLygExot/AaLIUoGja/J6AllEowIZH/ivqbTHsKo4dHdHYPwm5AsuKmiWA88LbdiygB5ix1P4DuziTKp1i1OelGRZ4LdLCiF0WTcHN7Z4MaRCu@TtoetlJJqyUoeRyMZyVq3FV83Te92I2vVD98H/YleoWaTXC@PCmJz/BGs2DSp7CWLY9YB0iZ6ilQwd3N87uj58df1U@fH@VBTdnE5BEdSzJpXYu4/HmNvnf6iNTAbIRZePoWm1sbzORulM99jh45bvrnNtnX7AbrAqKoiGtAb@TmfMomcRZcsBqh2T7o5s12OEENadRonG7YlAldNeFo4uqZn83ika4I68oiC6aADSAPdkyf3B73QfAsJLpTVgAFRLo1YuDIPspP5Fxn73GhYObUM3oqgGAtFPbZyeIc9ntgeOZeTwYpaZujuROoHAg53P5n0fY4R3Kh6NTUlY92fK3ll2vm3N57d@J9NFdSd7AVLhPudHgw0@PnTuRkmgME8SjKWR@Z/J//znm12wREp@/GHl69oD74Gjm6yEL9Od9V6@aiFgxWDNk@FONwGh8y0qcf10yG5rA9KxK4VvsQrOq2@8GuY@R6H2GtXltr@f669xGqHI8QAXQEwjA8hRK9Gr7rpN6ZI2Kl8/MBXkC9ikf3vnv51QsYcowTC6P47M8Xq09K@VzO82rYhcCn831Hr17@Cb38Y69I3v7j8fBa6DIOTCVFGO3r6Kx8Qa3PO9i1Es5CkJzdMJbeRwez06D7NWhLbi4AEmBYEh2Mg0Hp7QVyvqyGsUmoc@HlLDaNfCc9uI73setTqqtx2Kmxr@I28t@7Xa8Ww58ru4pNqMKvVqn0GDL5GNU0R/XeAFbrF6cvv/Jze4HCUv0lsyK31jTMAYxCDOPiqzpeR5ViHZAqxFUxn9YjhoH/1nLOfrove6VgP1e7vb2zPV8xni4oP7mEgdvuJC8cN/YXh7Q2TrhgNgp9fMFL2xfPT5085EUIFnw5wOVtRkKLD7H6ug5mN5QUtATO3mAa399YWaF3mGUS@X61XPYQEeUWSovw/ngolifWuHY7Dvy2awgZjHpLbkuqFqslPsgSlSpb1fLm9mfDMSwRPl5IvxKBCPHRannfi2croBuGvr55aQX0ZFhN/ccbqzuvegf//N3um60jt9X8suLkne8jCtsfj@wGjIObIqtFIGPHgrVLjcCTi62gNAp@GJY22uUWaJ6V7Xa4vRnulNd3Wpvh@m5zd3e31dnYabZ3t4PtzVazhGDvlKV43RuAluQw@2O1nYdVe5ditlMt73Y6lcrWdntzt7NbLa@vbzR3NtvljY3OTiVYX99qV3eau81Pa21JezIgYLXcxbVjXgI/vVu5yyzIdsnt/R8)

I use [this interpreter](https://github.com/stasoid/Alphabetti-spaghetti).

Alphabetti code before evil consists of harmless instructions and forward jumps. `z` in evil is skipped with `r`.
Main Alphabetti code is between evil and alphuck:

```
jii_iullluiiiocr
```

Pure code: `iiiullluiiio`. The number is formed like this: `273 == ((1+1+1)*10-1-1-1)*10+1+1+1`.
`cr` jumps to `j` in alphuck code and `r` in alphuck code jumps to `J` in Reng code: `~nJQ`.
I removed `j`/`J` from XPM image code, so the bulk of the polyglot can be skipped with that jump.
`Q` is used to jump to `j` on the last line. `Q` is used because `q` breaks Reng, `r`/`R` breaks Haystack.
I changed the last Trigger jumper from `Z` to `X` because `z` prints program code in Alphabetti.

Interpreter that I use jumps to the end of code if `j` is not found, but I don't want to use this behavior as it is not in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

## 275. HTML+JavaScript (Safari 5), 12980 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退 @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet     /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._'4o'6o@]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeeee;eecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<PLers 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}Vngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrs94 Cr ~-<u Uithw;re-  8hardoc""2:2FAC=' t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*  <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPl5m3O7mxySffveAdHoQqFA1CVQha4qkECzeWNmvDGrsRReeTyrGI3WuiN55ZXWjrDWYVtyWApHSK8OhZ/0A1p@2VBsaP7B7DknswoFECDZo1HEPmyRqMrPk5knT548@XWyafidX/wigQ87cruj864bsMDyA9by7EvL09j2iD0xbL@QX5YkDLXlnQ96lhP4JSnBdMYc64odOKbdAjcWuBeWY7@zPPDLM9b33HPP6LGgYwRgsSEW27W673vvA2a6vZ7htHwIuczYkQGe7YF5wYymH3iGGdiuA14rjL10ukav2TIYhLC8vmcFBL7AAIR5QXEmfVYZe@56voXJm5bvu@i4xtiG1esHoypYihDC8Gz32daLT6cirzP2qQE563et4VRe9Bx7ZVteayqGrrPPT/f3p13z7DPVddj@7fzpy@yl5xtdYxr@CtsaBO5BMO1eYFvnlmOwvLau5ac9V9m2Z9yKssY8y2i17a6l2Y7JVNaxun3LY@jC2q4HVRZY3WKumGtsjWNqJsYtjj2nwFbChxneuQ@e7qUFRgtqom9bLdb23B4zHP8KUtLXc@PwCHZ9khxMyCAQGvvKh9gti/mO3e9bAfeE4loeeUPKrGs7FxKnviPPbQ1M2zmHcBbgtT8IqEy@ZEK0KusLGtbQwBKEBR4MsnDi9qx4XfhAvJBrv2@Zdts2OXKsYWA5PpTX15gNdXdld7usZXUhwhi6mWG@ywZ@zKnZNTqaqUmIXEyF9S66zGZmv8@4FxQDsrSfKzKr535ls3fg3@34bNjvMd/ugXdguu22ZbF3Vr8D0VmvJbVcicFj9qdKFtkWLQjjWFC6naMvAW8BotNpQ9ZarBkLB/mgPFOJDccF9HnMMXqcGsz@iEoPYKIYbdfV0L3lWr6TDNiV612wpmUaWGxMzLfO28agCynabawOoAPbZz0XvlCJDoNsQeQAcYGwMTFpZkEwmbB6rT40TKxeF8kF6jqs5SvPAPrwfFGPgd0D6rCDpM8sw7eRY0EU33JaRBn9iJe5UNp4pbNLGxoeoGLgEWzf8oj0CS7DUgBII6JV5cqzA6AILMUWO7IMj516lpXidGr5ptFHKo0nCYm5mEKABdGIMDc2knuH@0kgUB5DM/pAkN7y6be/JRlMq7DFRhl@FVkuS3svdtn14hmaOc8EIu57ipFila@Znz07s@A31JvZc@9GAqgSYKXLsm4/yBpqHzKoBpDBrIFGNKmXea3fjSXMNqbqINZseKgW1AYwAfZ5hkpmDjwPufsYqcYFFLrrOueATyisN3B4la/moAqA/lp@hlmXFtIAryP3ijB82gEKgX8IGuMsvMMhhEKXA01RYDRM13e7AwoHMf0A2yNgBaIixIM2@5y1DbuLUcAfQfFce5YPxIlxBk4La75nO1ZLY2E2iOt40BYvITkDgJIDtIZejLdQpiAwVIRLRUWvD7/5O63zc4CzZZqu1xLk@jkQu0ldo0GZhc6NIcG6jtGlbEG4DKbOo0MCl0bXbhGXM5yRSIIyQaleuYNui1FDvbKhyXUMYLYWMAgzsDiRu4MA8phhPeOCc0SbUy4UvGc0oWIpAUqbiq2yJztQSyY0c6IZtTcI2kWm9vdY0s@@VjZLyubCmQWZS2mppcVs9rwMBKctkRPYkndRzudbE12FHxi@a7ek/ijouE6eqSaTzYrbtxwlOQEjmUl6zWRKQ06tpMp2xdTattNSkhtAi1VIOJkqmxWzZpfq5ano8SQBzBWCweZqKWZKRlZDjeIy2wPhQgNO9rkqTDE/128gytFbizkjYqbdLrlDgkQXpEsXCQT4kOZ3Lauv5DQ9hWwCw80sN3rMKukUDFHgkl1PJxPJdLzoBAFKOlFQbKyntotsq9vvoLwBSHH8PvBcD2nXNIB6fOzUAhDpMqxJdE09IXAW4olXVhK4dhMYaUhH1CR5k8P4KjJKAWHchCZbstWKNWRgAtCWA/8WN@66KB1QnrDnAdbhYKLGOVQNROYF2eIF4SmRy2SRLhxgKAitabGi2rShEWBzA54uaD5WNgi@nOdhABpvJDHe0zNG2Ktx0WDcYLBPM1gP2IM3YqaFPAeYj8U7FExkQO3PB7mXuW2WU/OFwmQbu9XEAi@7pX4HmPS77J0tCQsfb0zIaFgbxOyu4ZwPjHPgF64DUQzTtPqBYFRQEj8AVjTd35CjKjpPze9Ii0@m06ZOJBSPxmkgk@e1J7pCA7mLENtVkMlQ9ONjAdayPWBL0JNPpQ4BLqcSl99gkIkMvJHnZCGUAIDIrKFlDgLgakDAVx3b7ADNYu4czhd5JzSdPDjFUwfOrrajpDEzevVxXtKykRNmYy4IFWv0NhzoXBFUdcKBKj/ucDdkw@/NAOxGWYSOIOaqZQ0NaO8emD3XcWcABURGYDHIpA@vB5DETlAoho4rFLuosUaSclRFUGfANaDlA/11gqDvl6CfsIPOoKkBpWRPvdFBcOggsWQDb2QHLjc3u24T2LIP7TMbppA1B017OFUgcovq8CtfugQBrO2zCvTcbwdAdUqy7QPDJPcdDBzzkolxEwj@liEgBdIAUUrbJ1a8D0zlZOSYijxBlHKGydh25RQYMGKEmm@h8DaZza/AaTqXGCyeGS2LobK@Z5JBjcmkCB6DU7akRxNFe2AepUeyDK@20fUt@DqDbhetA4dzOYXLCil2LT16BKxNoeTsXr9rm3bQ4L7s8WMhU7AFGOOh2NRGmSkFcR6JwbQGDAXCiO6Hh9YC94SEXSUFBXl0M5Gw5Xmux9MNOp57xcgBg0lxpO64PeTu7BUJXChBw7DWdnB4L/pS6kqNmSJE1KeSvJxMal@5tqNcJxcWFpKlZBV6zIWFTTBtoGkTTWkwbZJJJROG09BEMTJkQt8axUC3evKmFkIepurYHIbY27@z@4pRK5WW6xmjpotvHr8pwDP0GBBaxQ/ASaYqFTSmUnL1CgqqNduTpd/BXu/E9Oy@QMK3jEuD2wUWlgkNUHGuhwODMgovd@OkV/FAuoDBgNlRvORZLXdWP7s@a6XPbpIZjJ0qG5UmFArSU3rauecOQAxJ1VZKql5PpWrLIHw0K8lccklRiioM42AkkvqkmEobHNtK0oLeUDk7SwJSBX5qZscjeMNMPpWKUAX5QIEHZG0lqV0XIf1mqp5KJyFuKpmBoVslmQTMmIgEnwqNbWkCQYfHn3HE7KTTEjVvGJXi71Z3Cm446J2MfjR49w55F4fRjCisOzC4lNcXAbIHThhWQ8@pQWvo1Wwz5KMTaXzqtvmoaAdfe8/2JWtItfXp4f7ecYWS6Rj@BcgU6jmGzYKsDFjxWhpwg@6gZUmzwgDbAJM5zgnOHWDi56bJVJdRMNXkmYh1FyabAw14DQmeLlO7vcki@B3I785EGQgIuVPMu@QXM8wSDz4zT1GS@8Cxd06eTUyR9S5AnmCm30XhW/V4AcCaXeKOLfpEY4wSO6AxmgMCJtAWyJetaC7AcR0VeWE4nHPjCfEJEQhBbihtoSRhT4RBwG17CEPiBM6nCNEfJVaU/ndcBwanlvaKuKHMgJHjbJWlzZT/j7ggpZn@uHWCpA/Gftcwgd9PgjuT2RkABA6Uzc72SZVvAZ4eHNA4/r4ygihlGg7ir2XTOHVg@x1EL4wlsBfw2oBVHKTi5A5h7YCZIOWeA6atoR3wUSu08BOM8tTwlRSOk7b4OAOpDGVkzFQ4c0cCrGvCCN8CWRl9@XQJ23Mubc91EMnaHoAGVlTGOpgCPgu9QEZbWwf53fn4nQUcMHbLWY/hNg51GrmmD63LcbvuucuWIACSpqZxwj5wcIYTRjmB0YcWZb8jBG2duzDUn6RBy4rmTFeXo/GmgSGzFF77CnoBNrvQ4wBzynxy8J09EEP0Qi4H@Q9tOXqiQsagTJcRHU02DiBWAbpIN1iT37H6nZE3QU6@K@ZNApo8pIbJZ7IMECEhV6KFv6Oo8UbOXaCdh16t0DSr7Hs0JsDJu/i4eqL0E9IKbzZQwsSUM7qGqJgAeqvCx/WLjOssO8G3oqkCtd1zAyP7uQYsGl8SSsiqzWQ/m1xIZlUV3zJ5sXyVZVvWZRa51BjycM8yZ8IeWpaZRV/s3FhomIme0HMOas7gcegFxeTfEAdRzOnyn6fTyNgpd1HaPNPQyZ92BpZkmR2XyWcwxIiXTIYOogNjZRUwDwIgjkuiaGJFSArcAQzrWlbX7tnBAc3Zdx0cu2jEvDXkWsJ3B/jNGMCRbYFAziccxp0MzquP@yjnnIc/Bk5OUGGIr3GUelYruzSG9tx1PRhX@kynOYV8hPqe8Mi6fr@lBUMAwGPtUf/uh/38i8PdvcbR1unTSnbge9mu3QQe0bIaPRjMdqE5zHkwbzhDuAe0Yztuz4YShSDfXXSPXTfgwgMuHDzsSWDEEMaz3cazg@3jreMvReaoR7d7g66BeSwtTgWIYJxQmDvBmG7TBdnCGcyFBMLF4fbhsxDKt14@O9hq7O4dHZ7GwHw16NqGPsz2L87nFehbGITpWo6j/rDbmlzRoWHqxCyCYDY45iozGJsyVYW3im48URyVaeiBIjJ2j6qKs8AGznN7LK/n1tdbTaNYtFZb5srKWttot1oreb1YaBcL@UIOXmur6xZ7T8FV1RrSzA2Y@KwITiBhGpB5@ujaSijhwFDUBIllNDNfke8dmTMLBWttZd1YN9fX1438WmvZyBfXLGt1rb2Sy1mreq7dLOrF5TszF8sGilZjW49mgKDV4WQBeQLzU@Az0Rx45kHWu2KtfD6/ahba68v5ViG30mqu5wrFVlNfM5rrVq69sqzn9ZaZ10thXJxRBS7RgQpDqdIB0TT0UnXwTElhZxqvYlplDJehBcNZXEYW0w@XkXHgIDxW0GMgFpFxala4F9A9XELGKRrhvoruPVxAHkuyZI0cRcAiBcR1ZM1rho7r6BitIE@srQKrFPxzlv/8SALytZ67QeBXuAYdK9@1rpP7ZdBuTzjnyflCxa6sO3ZeJme@Aj259isKe8trZuAI3grB4yvXM@Hd8poZOIJX4PBwxXs2uCmfWUEjYKsEDFfIZ8Ka8pgRMIK0RpDiq@pjvyL5zVtSF2nN9J4bKYK9TrD5annjK75a0RCL5UjNvIGcgiT2zAX5@ZmN8/btiRYjRSPwM0kOpxEmJ5LGPvnxMglTL2ev78hxQJwZ2M6FSwPnyNTIaXoBoUQgehfd2zHbMNSg10TQW5m67cP7r16zTa8ZAbDTnZ6ZIw@a9hRdP3S1RvaYPjgBOisHk1O5E8k3rfYARkHZpu2g@Z5g6nqRQrabTXteUMAEbj4IvzOCldjxAEaieW1F08NhLy6dAM/m87CnB4cUsGnQIG5y/p9NID8YeAHEEt//@t0WVMLtKuoYIxoLRoaGY10RfbTn1piIihZ6za7dca9PiCHTfSBNA5dcjW5kmA2aal9VO4bXwyGXqG4gUHwBJdxBazznfC4m/M5OpMQIyZPrDMyxe8ycEZrCTi2J8MRokN11jRahgQ@FbYsieVjZvBqsIR8UxgQe6HnmJTRj5YKNtwoEnUEw4G/cHXBfNdp9/N3VREXIXMFo6haIyEbTtu6odM@4GLRcFSQ9KjJmbHVG2HHpabJObXeNC25soHF28XkBPfv8HOQJ8Z0X7KoDYxsalGav6HMfXfjOwO@rTaisABoO2agp9O5Iwevy97wgttg/FxnmY83u0usBlR4RF5ELiHSEaNzSpMaQZk@huWs0RzhU73w8lWGCJOAAz6mY6XRuGbu9aO03vhVpfnzsKyn@@vrs2HwzFUfJrOFVlm@iUvkEMpVZbKu6p2Kh47J7RlfNt2LGuRw9nDoem2YEpXkb1ewaPpBWIKrDuoTqo9dd5I49kwnDLm9suoPYx9kJtwDMW00WbEu0atPt2j427e48Djq9ADdOE7ez0Ss2JW3PQmyLZCa/o0am2XzBNQNcyp1DaA/gcnwVFdepY5SjufOQZrpX@JsrWnTcS4u/Z3d072bm6gEcS@0SSdjmzB6lZd5HqbgdiF6z8XgxM1@B2Z3pPtkGwimO@ADtgXTt213XZyf0vgst5x5E4@/ZFB3HoG04Kq0Hxc2zo4lM9ZkmZlnn1KvRPXe7q8XzrAGvuZU/8NrYJ4jvQ7lfxL10/X7uFcpHrqOL71y2f5H1Lu6rO1qa8HDRPma8oweexcLEouT8AsJIAnfizC7cfq5IMbUsHy/PqwDP7FwZo/D7S/Qs87Ab9iz9EcnbIP5hhPUiGAKPy@C/TGord6fWehh7ugV27b5CxCr3omtBR0bvW1XK8jn9I2PoudzDmVW7O7AG1kxeddj8ysL97XeMQh6eqZwoxqKY7cQZIZzrjEK9E@PHB@Ua@3C03clgjK4NjfxeSWcmv@uDjN7HIfcRGI7QcDviuTPoT1TuxCjOOb4bc51@2LLd1kQm0edjOVLxfnlqQpD3LfrdObjig0Fc26qs5HI5Id/E5q8nLHcNupajuF/Z/D2RMLmMUx6HxdkQL2acncZ4KhWq3r7wVZzUfBh3ys@bEaDA6@tZx3asYITveVUyi9s2Xbf7MVUITLdlo/wGUiku/NxXlbdkI7EbjI3nPnycOWm258168A5JjE4Bezjwvosa4lOvD6pmFZesoZWeT1nvngeKTeTelwp08zS5xLdOdOcLnmJGRdeK2tqdLZKLs27T6hr8M1xduQveurZ8J7xIZBFyMq1t4XoYXwEbr6gmpvhWfwTIslswyOlYPYusd4wOjNZXAz/8zA00dPE3w1uj9cZ58fo2MAoH3xOrbTFRKnAdGJYFhndu4bimi6viwnUecw5n1Wci96BnnFv8XNVd3HM81YFbh/locGycPelR4rvOTIjGt37cTQrQmC6skR9@ZwJ8PjKhPge9@6fqptq9SRuV7mvoWnbmYsI9sqLTcTtOx@rwnUCRbV7zAIoM@Im4uwoB@T/vmIz4U3yXUhyzXbfbfQhmkT9ybum67Zl52sNzWi2I@lFwR0YTPMTn3ilA6OsJQdTpz2s3HWsAXZbvBm7fUsk2L2gXJ4v4ex4XDRd3ftlZqDtnCAAj4feXhX/v2PTccIN@nz6Nfnfg04uiqnS8blZV7lMyD6EKO@DbjjjdWudu0@zY92WpaRmBY19kwxkhbr1zZNuPYcFm6i46a10bkOeNNKSGStz/BD8H86pUTC7xbisyzK7jEtsZeN4IMRG4LvO77tWYP0zun4imcfnqAxrm5UCsDM7wJmkAd9aFO8juWAIRC4lzCYyEcBS4VSsHAos@d0ZpYntnrHUsL/PXPLloqvyUqdj67cdMiYptDzQ5aMdmbsF9gn4mFqNndlZOZ3Du32Z3fMK@BSIWvmbW9NY5nmmeqmheqdADGY74zMN3vpvF7dvwbUDNDaw7V1cKdy6vUDi9qxquDZ8GfKAOB3Onzbp23@dvprbzMwWG20vIt0ONZg@bRf20rDZfC0HTfZJez/XwEBGIFKrpWb6JU@nIkbn8xLmP454DZ1a7bBw4DDuzCLdXrWdWf9TjqV@8sM4N3F75zMadlt0ZVAFQpxev7wP67YHh298euIE1E970AvZ94J4b57b5dALzIbAQo2IPHv9MkD063Ub@Vcf26fxGaLhjzgmJjJMt0lkD5P1Zo7Wp6froYPTd0yoxQUns/WbqAQv3iEcGXDBAf2NmWrNm4t0@jRtHZLprEt4OaGZWfGdS1exNAHclfzXo9Qe@@MxOnfbpxKeoexfk7l/ZwBbVt8CNWcfoBrOnsWMzsyBziU5ybJwnhX/H7rrn7DvFHAMRDTptFMpnENw2dNdHRgAtwplBwJT2AxdKcdJD9XjB3gJNWMtMtR07uHuCJwgMGCOFXywM72zwFGL2Gb61Jx8LQT2djZFnd0ow0LePzC4eiv/YkQBnu0CFJ3RoHY3Rufk43YtkrB0BMOxdHOsqPl67c9GnhF2q6wwCFXf539WnrN7Zp5TYsLgaIw2mfHvv@ctUnEJo@@t9cqgFA8GB3x2NTXM3HkwRnu2AsDafF0@GDkcTuxapNDimjZr3xNnq4@kpYvm77qwRz9EIep8HD5mgAxn0di0TVx7vTfuF@xxEN@jK@sB0e8cWbhmY4iWzI2K0Z65pdAE/rXuTOSGwM/qK8eDa6FtNqN/u2DRbFpsFeNcIjDmyE00c0ggwMt1LK3a3aXlf0YxgzDxvUDuZoafWkIYh8wmGt0I1ME0ucOO03EQbmV7b8fuu6/A3MeEcfPTndzMb6B7o9fAVdw33L0/0fjMHaZOlPbzk202sFj@4N6@4ntV0u/yNRZjDDhybby4wPNvys89sZzAkN6aC7DZ7mMO38ea0NZzm8DvQ2K5sGGNHu3txsxrfKuxPjaRAJL40fFrynz2mmdhJ/PBdRR3DM11cOxOGj1w5ix0Ju4ePR1ul@daEJlTKEBiaYQ5CvQL3ZLXba/boNXdMEqvpY6uJR@6adH40MIazhMjJo2PCcerwVsjSsOGvMuUIRj2p@zuy6SHbJMbtPr2IoV/NJJMwuRe2Zb4zUvfw0qgV0Vxy1qAR7cyGNLkJDsScrqUGHdxjmQ2CeQzjhX0xaD1grStcQBn0LFyznly5mUtUrt8hinBnr9JHDNezxNZt3CUITT80I9dVt@aSLIKH/8Ptb2WhY26sruAJ/sFQPQd2dv@@AMj8wHPE5yFkd@T6QdseHvZRjZPrzeMvWKwCRIEPbw5oWppXCKhPZ9Dl8x3nsR1dvRaN70AabLtg6hILDyzVci5VUnE0DJcrPSPUIzO3Dqc3h@r37A698qP1QPBQ@z59s33/6ODZ4anW9/U7Zg5xw9/A7uLqHmUldIMCkmn@FPUJ7VV74GKFCh9cjZv4zN8f0e8YTSswssbcoQ76WsFsue/p6fNn6fG5ZabsdDy3Z6Xi3jsnJxnIOfvWyUzveOx9IPC2O5wb/WBP11MzKPClQyuC87jejJTmQTq1YMAK9PSUH6G9V2Yy3b7VOh31rc@hQ0TO6z8w@dW5hXxhXNrn2JDY@lxEUVtj69rqShjkcxiM45Gou0cln9kgx4J8btI3dU/oY5IFln/pJf9p4YTlxFaEj4uk58JZNEGtgY1HC887ZPqVZU7X9XnoPjHaUL2sQMgWZ8tIDVakMMXPiFOP4GZ7QrOCr4U63cQRUerxw8NK4GiY5gAnJ6GyNUYBFcVIp1MpScR66l6xHiqMwkg@nXS@sPtllguNWPYOCHUUHnU9KGzRYBsVls/lWCpV5mpTgAMAWxtYZda2Q9Bbvm@fO5CFMAek8Qq14XBlWj6DkWMQwq3V2OL1sJQr6TeswuSSzOp1nmN8KJG9YZ/UVR3z6LVFo15ZTKpqcjF55pRYLhkFt7q@NTu4MREWMosfkeEIv1yVnUt66CJslrm2H5BkUJNWx3BaQOeCL0D5Pa6zhitEOsUd8H/5hy2hYIwU6fVs3@gCQlBHILCojnu1ydMN0dXvG6igDGFcdXB1A1NXd7aYf4UrFVyvGFTXy/3TotBWJBQSguWIz19HueCUg4voePI64ITBcxOdohUJR7HCQsGQftBzQIZuBR1fYyc2HaoeeONjUkJNoxN4uFLWyrAD1rJwszGdlaeF4a7rXtD5OczJX/4h19FEJ@bFSeYwedLNFksRD8brpBjJNN0B5DoE8s7yXBFEQSQbZjDAbRikGpDcU3iOnJRHAbWroeokSobrT9rZOmHqHkui0kFUdVK228ri1vGnn9dy9crXrJe1/ut3s6lrgTj5E3V91ZczLAxSvkHCinsXwHvsm2Ty4lDmCUbqBGzBMq94faDCRE5kqFEgpDHX7YfNBkeBpO0tokahRUVBM9VzqEOpR5rziGCtK9KhROdWHRRLSHOjDw0MrCkCzVtdZVEZ8J0B6knACpAg6qEywMR17dEBe9QHhFEWh@w9I9EBmJleyIGNI7KLKqh6le3wKMpy/IhQdtdqDmib/GVeyxcqVJzFRmWjSiYQM11UBVd7fTbM59Sz4dpeHQa2AqlnZ8NPcvkvAOuuB7EeZ7Hl7b3YvV7Uqrn3731jxGT5JlnmR5qATSxeHx0c7Z2cbp2@PIFauAlZ2z4/2BjyGqQiOqvccbukZA/wgiPMj@A/kW3MBlGNayolxU@VUlCBa1mVF7kxxpomYt8TfVZ834r53w4geFrbZlLUMwAVGERsiDUs/KCPqgKZiCvUnRGV2dh/YAOKEIMHx2bwUkKVzCqALBWQ9UBUsfmF3eRuD8HYvVDuRtvmzCCIsSi9WuTPizgTBTe/knL3Dd//@5ebQ7m73BTmjnJD0Mg1jLO/dfDs5fHeZLSwkyeuW1kviOPUnDljS@Oj1FC/G2kxERFxZ0VFZjJF4FbRmXEts1ZwZUGxBHM0ezwyUSjlX5bGhAmYqaCi47qQQhSFcoDyDQoi06e9YQgZy2LYR8fAXfMiRkxgX45AhxnXZAE5QQp7NXzCYiBUga6w6R0RExf8OunHxZ9M2OKwaNhHD3ze5uZ0VVGv4zP4j/VKoSlfZ0MmujO9zlSWh1/Xcs6hwGHYVJn3UWyRI0Je5HmXo/yiolXIU@srgxYz6RSTOCUNvXTX6PuhMJhgL9zAKrG3A5c0sYTMJJIvSMevwfUiU9Vybb@k4QXGUSBQh/0WwTvYP6mgdMZFM@LvcZobONhRQSCuoljoSgg8VOXND7FzXaEc5a5QSxl2lTQh6As1dJGU4LNL27dhUEWV0EYZpwucEksjCo5qrkkHD4wNfJBJWtB9g4QSYFcLwolGR2v5@VrVYXICaFKLRMYMkyUM61duqymErvQKR3lveORFCkeQ/RjM5MaCqgLmzm0n1GldQiXXNBdWYoE3wJ2z1eStKGEWSmRSO0GvGws4Q2HrmZX98Ju/w5W0ngVg/qEwD3PbYPt1YWuD@TdCH10H2z@LbHmw/YjbXmexym5rphznM1IyMvcwMhDnE/lWwZAxhNq9qUBRlWN1f35wxHwTlUZjhfZgrD6uK2Qz4TiF2T2gjEuqaAzOUxjX4xiOUsOBLxAXEAnKOCjWUHqWV1dQSWEpm8WM4xqnRluYrSHfVkQ6C98OUFcvSGLZ1cLqip6FTKqXIUBSo3SOJyo5wFSqBIxRurT7lTdNk21sbDDZN42uVVktcwLJLhqvl@U3UUYXIazERws1BnEgyjgG@FVFNGXRSOspjIq9WVJPImNruZzeQCRUyABBUujshIpXQOZ0BaqAmB1rGJDYNApHQcC1HTempDsEpAIgDhs1yk63yfEpSZyYj7VSLV4N8isMRjNTJXkWxdZes7PgzKkLzcIMqO9nM@jXAfM/maFumFMWKpa6redWmdZSi6VhT04cF9c39iG3TMln88tZfTUVo1BZgIL8Ynt/DyChhQPHMC37K7fvb@3sHXzr8Ojklr4zCpmcDpZkyepG@kzVMrV6ZEhG@Z5E6vZ@9uT59n6IyniuxisMGGK8ZXw6m7NSm87pnNRf8QOpt9Mmj1sJ6bmHAqbpSXWfjl7chj72zcYC7vDzcLdSVVLXN7X6RvXMSdxK/v0sHdYJbQmJC0xnPmmwTk5nE7MY3VdxivdV@FqobUFHVQt4BjdwL8aKG4RDzIMHD6EAB5C0bBhqHvOEDBzyGaCxhqE8vzDDJ9bHZ4lIs3CUo1jI0/BqDWxaY4WYQhNkx/A7XbspQQfeQu2oXI9TqKgo0gCl@f2uHSgpiaZAKigGARNTxAUbw9JQo40RCumxJlgZdpdyyRBeSoJGAPCSRwO/w47cfmxua9cKTccgjbDdAV81t9i3Bj0I16bPsYUs1gL5RIXIgKhklFU@qoaWJXRLDtOovxPSq6GGSVFwrdcqKMOU1rGGLfscGLiSykBL/0QHsSrSfoGFJn2TThJ4HMfwp3gOMY7Sj1IxOhwDN2qGZjsta6igzqxSHeRTdE9evbpMpuRbNEB6TndCzYhTCk/DhmgEokWMlYVONbb16FaNKY206@uodwwVeUC1QIongfcMjNA/Ke2e0WfKgDTx@kxjZFXOFCfjB16KqVWuzMdh6TSNquFDHiA1Y9A2mYhwmILzkEq2ArWDrr7Tws87u89quqbVwUyJpNgizqjtQFeOc1EpCUZJEKVEYCtYt6yEOeLUq3HKgzjoL5FqQIbqaGd4kwJZmnx3ERdUalZ9HFOpNm6BHKvr6yVRG5OsZp0BWdzm8loWwM5gIaGUCvgVehkAa3jBAt7EgctywBaefGY5jgUIAprpGdAHGwMgMi@VCW/UyYwV8lMKCZ7Fp0LRA2R0UlH/XvK6i3s3FrNlmpwp30Cf@uYMO9W26FZH2f8xq2XL18pitzLKgqCTqiqLnYqeXl5KpxedJWXRwa7@8WOc07lZBEmiocEQaQiB1MVuqgz0DJJHZdEpLxobymKrkl@iGGCFQdo1RPjaz2rXi8ZNdvEx9NQZcPF441UWfdL1mtM0/Qbyhy1kMZsBmrlG1Zh0nQ4mv2in05gHbbGBGfg6e3aSJp59dpKl6aOykEaz5z3R3Ka4alQTty4T4ggUzqKigbHnkbGL8zWNMPBYTf/yLL85sgdP@DNcMmC0a9ry4@K/POnzcMYi@F2S1PBxzbpc2S4gcKgAEtGaMVIpYCa/@EVCX2Wysri5uty9TCcLuTK89PIaK7BPFs/yKwmWeGIYAQzZs0vXZ7vF80tmtfOrb1W1Zre1t/Wji6OjL4aj1JmSTOwcvpb1FQi6xtbp99BnjeXnPOzjnkRiKSslskv647Vs9s2bNyDy4lOratUwiFZP1dRkvaasCYdedW1tKbNaXMocP0k2IC9Q3JSSz6dOmG1n2Znd91st@LkdutxKSfCHbW5iemCAfybcesM2GYdb1vn5YM8YcXc7McDPfiDiPv/Oq1ev0PCKHvbuWMRPcIgCXKLUMAoJymQ@l//LP124yVwfNTb@8nu9rLWAn0P8/PDmOZpP9MInCwufbG@vrGQAcdx89J2jL7e2tlZ2M4WjWmFzRc0tbPzFny8s5PMb@exC3ff1erJ28YWcz63I2l/@frJxdPRt38e6w2eZ6WDEdxF@OisU2AV7B89Fm@E/md@1YmYDzc32O@wgQViuELNJJgvLyZPXSayfdwld1xMj@mtQ0RaYXt1c@28/PnybCBLVfPaVB98g8TaxWkxwIxjAthzaLhPVxAYGW71JjLKVSgWMa//t30L86rcADvqMNuBVLYSwVkeJqlqhKO8T1VUw6Pk8pPt/f/e77EkNHnllLS9v1uFZwmdDSlSHkLVq9WCf5av5JUE8evGx/phMTtABseMsoRdXDp@Q1baeHOYL@Q00OxZeFQRjVBoH63r@jIkq1UXFIhJ0fHMH1gEz1rSbYGHQMSWwkM7YqwRRDZANUQ43CwciJu7wajrcqzPDWFpLr@SfOOVXsWfC8qt/jvFGttWFJ292s9mNKvT@@JRKT84aoull2VpRdt0nOCFYZs@EaxlfQ1dVXQgOvzNyVPER6EsUK5kGR1HY8kIfNraxuFNCYJJFjeyXCLeHz1/9@7/6yV/9mP5@Qr//LCXC/VZq7bJeDR@gH7nqyddnwuo8Z8/54zjwD7/Qii7oACZHzFcmoqdaxRf9CxuZ6DvlJnyqkYVCjKPMDcdCLkbpSomvs1mGLYBdhoV5slBaKJZWS/lsIyweFYPnnAzPY6Ubl4@XZxOeBfijf3giK74XyEU4U5DbzwKrPuSZ2StIiVqiVq/zJl2N18/dz7GGNKcJWyPez1xKCRVYVzp9DDTKBGnDc5a@53kJP01rCFtWG0NNSIlf@VOVWOIannpavbmpaa/T5bL4B5GvHNnw4SbIWnLFTa66T@o3qrrxuppO1yintarI8obK6lVeAHprjdcbAD69UduouDv004hE1Prram1jMjLFr1efPEkjap8AgOpincFgA2rjZuOmelPbuLnZ2ID/DXrfiC@43mzc@qfP@JkTZuxfx/o/q2WrZ1nRJqt1sGvZKrpo2TMwVOEL4aBTkBLXSDqsVicthhW1pq8W6iqjBrIEzCtb0pfyy9nC8JPVvTzwAB@D52U5u4SG99iDggy0LiVwNLHOBxXr5PDmwzf/J/7OPnzzr8EKecPrIsm3@Rb/nr3Dv7cB/p2a@Hf8Fv/Y6Tv8Ow7w73kT/458/Dt9i39bTfw77eGflKgwBnLd4maum7vM6Rf6BRhslgOxupPr6C3ofFjOYrlRbsRyPVdvgcmCvxyY7Fyb5c5Zzsk5ug6eYAhYLkBTGz7n8NcGKB782bkcAs9dMkili10aKQSn7/sGS51JNZZ8Y4EwpulaTlu1G/XCav9tLVkvJ7JnZ1kuobL8SpkUwN/cMNZo7L3YbTSy2CDOnruH4//Dw17ceud/79B9fuj2XPg/PDx8fgYsrZp@klafwFOppjfEZzNRLW@elVQk5pCsE9mNzbPqsorm1TRQah7d0h/5jCHCt7pwJsEI/tWrqzL1u@Wry/JVmQyRlRsaIoAIxg0Qqyz6a3CBeGevstTHXsFzSXDJhsYr8AxN3JB9dXWGciaMKqJ/QEfc@iv4t/@/9f/8JVNq9RQ0guubDYWeFP6lUtc31zfiXU0pirAoG/CHDmDHKNc3VTRSoGsw1ZRUPXVzw93graQ2OMAqprFRpcjjgMA8ElGalC5/Kb/aL6bNn7MkCE4w3lbEYuHZ2TCXS5Wb4BKtGBjvad0pVaYdOYtNXCuEMaaeohCFlXJZX@Lm/Eq@XF4RlrViuVwU5kVFWb/9VHOb@ipIBysrqVS5nBNhYTRZDo0AwvINs4yNvJxIYWZ5y1dyOGdJV78k5ZL8@LEiLgva7PdTjx/r67n37yOnRqNle40Gui@/fy83ZNy8U1kvgD1XfP8emE4y5XrKC5cvGyuqzj7JVymFddeDUq2BN9Oz@XGaHcM3gsBT3tn9jIwbfn05ReracznXO0v@/Eff@95ZsoLbOch1RUcAmAorbGysrlSrqytgXi1CweVFvj9IOU@v66mbxazMi8vkxWRCeOnFtRS53iTRnyU22GYVGqqPD7u@SVD9sZVCSmmOrNQ1uIRu@vo6d2Qrq0oxvS7@KgspVl1i4g96ruX0ytLa0hMYzgxvP8hUy9dGJZnNJm8q10YJ57Zuyqa4FgSP4hmPHy@vAzKLufKZ1Gjsbp1uNfBGUVy5hw6RoSNxaAlXZfteskYTkYX1eg0LVj9LJkvlJ1TterHAEsmyCKcmgduz4jqVP@H7kt3GM7lDgjr1W0r0mb62DD0tdLRSnzZRreVYC9ehPea22wvgCHXHmrhlwLe63fAqlSvX67au7Ja1ICWOnm3t7J1m8iC1JPL7WzuZ/MnL7YSO1sLYjt4ssYwOx3tbu4cvIcbRs72tk71PDz7fe3kE7r70lffOsCzDGlhW42owuHrLvrLthg3Y6w5s23ZND3LRsCyrD8Gip2xZpu0bX31leH16GOfWH372gw8/@58@/N6PPvzeDz783k9@/s1PfgC/P4Tfj/j3R/9mvYDvn3/zz/7gw@/@Hjj@Z/j9J/j96c@/@e3v8h/Z/wx@/yXm9mfiFwvHfxLA@vWff/Pj3//5N7/xU/j9C/H76e3fb/7p7N9Pvj//h/F@/Ad3h/nRv4XfH3FYYdgf/S53w@@t8L/Lw/3GTz/81r/j/38h/tD4ex9@68/wJSz/9Kd/8V8@fO8/5PPFv/hXH37wow/f//GH73/vw/d/@OH7/zj/4bf/lZ6Lv/7gw0/@@L//yR/99z/5X@j/D@n9Rw/5//DTf/rX/9df/8e//hPx@1P4/Tsw/elf/wcg3b/945/h/4//@G//08/w///4l3/7x//r3/76/06G3@GG/@df/Bv@/pvv/eBvvv/P/@Z738x5/@DO9zcPcP/mH8Dl4fl8CJyHlOtjXb75pfLz98HGOBWgAbrnhOVBqN0eWTSh8cmwJH3CElWaYMI5p2K@mF4CeXRpfT028QRBmATt9Cf/5MNv/xqQ/28BMLD9z2CDf24Brx@ShX3xxYQnS9MkiZr@4gv0FOPKL@KhfggO77MgneeevIcQX5A3f1gUDNL93ygYhGMiWBhuMgMUBneGcveff/PPf588orjo/GsTIHOhczz0IgZ/Hxb1h9jux6WJh/4hso4PP/vuh9//xx9@9jsffvbr2FeoK@uZrQx09XfPDUPAwgPCYcDVh4SDgDqOK9kCW5DyYFjYwPlMSU@/eQO5XwATDMGWpMIy2CS9SmYdzRAxDTYCMhym8Q3/0so6Qwu4DMkVviwNXttpVqlU0tKwAn4UFKwYZ8iqRXAa4vxDBeBiJB4n0yjC4IYNtwkKxKykj1ljqTLkEdPoUCUISDYSOh3Lel5OFyu7kGBluMsQFgJPS2/g@6ZSLVaGVQT3NWUBYKS3IUkIVcHcDatfg71CMCG8NNz9GrJSrKTT1SK4VLCQaUot06A09QIVjsqeZlRudGcMd2huPoEmI@tFmc@PACqZCI3v9Dg0BoTg4H@WXhLFof/QSL8ljA/1NCT8cDfuv4nOFF8EALiqihv74KeqmJsn4D3koNKULHzSHAJgLk1SVQgSHEiASUtpqt80WSB9yMPHPRvIKhAcFmdxcRFMG1V5WW4cwpgSBm/eRckPDA8XHkmwLDF5dV1GZ9wlxfd/Lh7R4HNpdwneOvzvLdCeZypLeUlaTOLMRpJnLc0@SfPfkydL7BMoO33HbhJT08vuipvgxdxIp@U8JFl1wbZERUwTIJx5oP@09DohsQTVPTSWDH/DR6uQe6wpkcPripQe23E@UsTQtIyWyYivRl9y0IRBI1/x1RZJguTDIKavrtDJF7pcLsVSVD@mhYIYk57759vuEEYgGVnO6Ku4YJUSEzmnpTy2VWmvlIP3l26pVPlaX1mT4Ev2Ad5zJ25cA6rpWJ6lbWwg9Oq1StNNaAQJdlWqVsVaPdOl6sneKQQ/PWR6PqcxGL1cr6zlVworhfzy6mphLa@vrK6vrBaKy8BXV3OFfF5fX1lZL66v3US4egKsKVNaahY2qv/o1vM//KNZz2xXfKTqF2yo0QT7jVTtVvie0UVct5fPcnKZpr4IlYu1XAb/8svL8IZ8ZvTCWn1hoXutYrHPaKPiNe6MgKxK1yp2e4/gYdIjiT0CJ3ggDVy5ZGKvycFhWewrwOtq@d4CWS8AGUM9nAEdc3DS///86p4Eu76@jv2kxMJ3vhOwahVGdOrBvpQAbtZh4a4E1W5pHY1u7G0NPIt8zxnbPfj84OTg8IW2e3ACQ6wvWX45p0mJm5ubdrRqRlaLHR4eStiNwNB5Wcf4NyYbDAbk2wT7zdCQ@vGnPGHrS/m8ml9Wl3VVX8b/ewx5/H94@Dz85/ENsZbzEj/w28VDVOG05DoyTGmDq7Cp4nWTrtGqRLcSMyV13aq0XJMOR5XblVpd84G2yy2t6bZGmh@MYFTdsv1@1xhVks2ua14kQ08b76nC84CVrJHVGg3Ac@DCUJsG55v5tUJpIetlNdw4rrRZajO/ugYuZ07oBC4FdHk96bReamlhjp5DA4J4@VJ@tXCzITTXVaE8mK8q5uJaZK7kuI51g5uFS0Yb0HBt8k02JTlfKMo3T3pWyzbYWQ5Pol3PDLa6Kt@E4SAhHJfjlInSw3tjcMt5KXeWS82Jm4O4kD/KlrQhdORUaY9EDXhgHa/TrNU3Qu05Venrr78e0rak0oETiP1J@ZUiujMJ5wEegzz1WOfGwurYmEPjKWo6egEVBZzbYc/wmEHgslOXb2fftsw5IXY6Bt0uuuO5vv/3CLNtOBfca9fmKlcir6cG6lz3e3bQmRPiZb@HJ1It7x8Mwl6vCRlEAuIBtuHldV13VoA19vJoTimfRxrScCsTqUiD4McHnz49jX1P97Z2nkqrbPvwxe7UpyACFdizvf3TyLrGfcOohQjEl3vPnk1bxQeEgjJNWC2wwhpuZQ4t0M0njMCQMw25Vi8nADHBDQjPxXLLGWzqjx/rG0fP8LjAKlsBeXt5LVcqLWYZtITyzedQtsr2RamPu6N9q7/kV/eGR56/vgLlZV@rGwP2EirhquxZIEoWgS6gXcoytMb9rZ1KkgWL0nPcQL2u89OAti/RoVy8vhKvqg0kVMnScq8cOujY7A4sNuizuY7wQSc0evZ5J2DBlRsGkJqGweD3sQ/Et@JPcLdDwNMgt1s@3RnBcceO3WY5SSOGm18vForry/liprheXCnoq4VCRs9n9LXi2jqIHTm9qK8WC@t6priyvrwCshH4FtbXpASIC3Y7mwXxU5dl@JYArGPijUsbeHWVq3WqUoLPI7N3ipGCSo/sAyZbEEfGuz/9gM6ILNkVOb@CB7iWdQYQDWayxP7@Tm5/X5a30YLLXDs5WW6hpVDM5da2Zdkinx2Q3/Ky7PI4RTyZLgfckstt78jygANA/W2y3EHL3iqOjWXZRsvO1v4@ptNGSx7jQ7AL7sMt3dCyBsEctCwv0@Balt9G4CDcFk9ohXK6hxZME332uc8O@Mnyp2F@cjmAcMzDcQhPw7JubcnyAbdsbaHPDhW8wLP6GVq26JFlDyxAhLJ8DoZz7AlkuQlGJEVZNsFkjgxww9utUKeXA81PHnEEIYpkeUihDfNChiGgcMdknj59anSClnXOn5HHv9CoDsDHHg729puffto8P296o629T4/RZ2fnqdEeDbzmeVNEazbgcSEO@Fz0RtMP5PGg0TC6M30@Ax9nyqcxaliYt4bxFvIknnNMpNfYAZ8d8JkxFz/k0ODpQdAmPts9@G4bTfIJH/Kh77DZlMtIqMGob@HcObaZCwd4QaZnmJ5bRvuwssCSSjIzqq3m6mVyZz2Fpa6BY6F/W6EblHH4BIL29ag2rOTqlWFlLS8Ominy2TBfsOXMQm9TXwcpxNjU8yvpYQkV9LvtJEuq@qaiP156p7wAgWN5pSSfbW6qck2vb@b1Yml17fXSQJZTJXxvLq@V3sEYKwkDKXylamv1TRBtxlHW1tJGNl9awx15qfINYCSA3qg5CKxGQ1GuLOMilcIcYx8P4hYVl42oqHa5rQwzwwrPGBulysOKXubaZVjuFqwWqjcb4GWlHOI5gBtu5kq4fqHI@npRhvSzWSWVQq6EfAS@b16Fy6vRJ2aYMPJHYyWV33SsF1dTGh5barjtBt32yN7EQ443J0iv8KQhaRkINwTT8N4vSac4uMTugKQqu4lXrJMuiqE05Ir5GJ9v1NfWJakqxlZH/La5srB@@nRHg@GWsKG6NG0fZVjX0/BG@GDCh6vyCp1OoXPTnlq4zdcM3Xb4@X9tbwhjaRSEQ49n4uyZJnScaKdPy9dqAxc9vn16cXr6hXoTB3sC40yeETwnVSY9G6hxAJXL2S1mVKpgMlogZlMuAQWpK0JHo1qtNCo9q9cPRlDmMN5nXAX0GNCBzwsTnd@i6Nd4plF4NCq5m3H4F4Me2@aB6OBjGK1R2Qb85soOqma10LrIhomhVG2h5rntyvb1oISC6E3Zqlie53pyAk@LbjqVgeMbbevI8vCg4sHhImszC48Emp03Z3sYcgcF6hu16jFnIh@KoVabqUmnmBVRp3w7wsg1bbXHZbobGIUor1Plt2DzFpnS0rZTmyvllrLNGilwyb1pv2mzPFtdKdNFJApCAnZAmEOMGKlK9TMAzOFelEqQEUESFwATE1qEGrFb5GOk@vZN@bxSw9Dv8bWhynJdVWvv61K1LFWBu5RHCaPiD5r8yuBcU8/nVstDcNPXVsod1qw0Xw/LXqUPQ0xW7kK1i2kIfn7AwL3kgCSA8@698uHXvpvaUAsV7lYmWO@7IEg0tEZlOK6g5Uotv7Kaya@u4KTF6jL89Ex@OY@7YzP53Homr4M8AXIGxIffGthX4AdhQNzI6zi1oXQVmTE5kxvmND2jW3pGyb2xW29SmQsFpEBCWCoTuHsOUA04IPEAyZIVvkYqnV/qKi2XGRsq0S9wuzIV0sh0WN/OdBDMsWV0efCUypaXlO6igmEWTwf9vVq9VNob9r@NXor6dnM1vZZLv0ulysoCS1V86y1hGBkjoaC/ANQspmuYP@jVcgtQaGh/6g3UdLCor@VLtcFiTdWhdLn35xtyVa5DVd0wCf7ia8Agb5XBLeSBXEIby1hjtz4K1V0LqlVfz5dFEKkvOLIiK2dyeNRFSSbX8slkKlnGKcoFcBccndhvErqD5GN9UwYZTy7J63nwHzPyWzng4/NVXUrcSDiCZTBST1xLN9c3G/FdgJ@x0chIq6H1MWPn6UWJZWlzjtZIsAUyqVqVJpK3Klvnx1tlEXprR0qUaJ/qeC8hOxO6CpiaXfjYLUHpjepr/j3DLXGQrEQqEWusTiv8lo3jJ/Y5Ht3aZEkol@H1avn8cr2WX4O@HHhwGDSfh6L71xLHN99Dlt1IV1n2TJJl4j58w0GxkOKlYF8nqL2znetw@qL0HIfNTDFKvH3X6qmvX9jd6@KyyofeCkt8zdJZjfZBNrJfJ6B/vKFaCLe8fvYmX4B6cdzQAQbZAbB26E4LBTnF2ALfYp2PtliHOxU2yjgT@4b1T9Zfr70uvn7@8vDl4T57kisVS8WppZazJ5mMntSTGziMe7/g4qDta@db32ZlVk70k8sryVurM2eVxLCyEm4zUfRqVdU38mwTSJuVoDto66tq7n2V02mVPFbz4PPh1366Mtwogj0P4nQJEF1I56tVfSmfSvQ/fPOv8Qjs9d7nW89YEhWS/N2f/35@7e/@/F/SnobkTRnd8strCQiJRn11LXF93b@@voGH@xUS9QTP08paCsx8v42eqGaFs76mpxK@mhAz2GuFhP9eaChS8rki@O0ccpu8CihO7B3bhbz@ZAPRrN9CMyDa8tcTUqL4/M17xsBiVlvn53aeTNnsLcQtlmDgCv84ft0Aw8KbSnUxixPy6xg6nClcqlarS7hYxpLVNB73zpMqiGrtplwHpOODA7wlh/4sfwn/0P6aOyz5PthDb2vpK38Jc8cKVajbpWw2@@HXfjufX/27P//Ns9T7xvvGF8C319fXV/V84heQjzvOYIajOpoTwtOUaIhGg2zOTamaKUsJvD63zXj4cGyIo0HUQMD1N6FNukThhKqgAUg0QBRXKNgSniTLkFBOx85TZUmKJFcSur1zM0Mw2BKqpYYGJ11Lj9ALujxWAVYnPRqDAoceKn4yG3534PVJhFQonl7PsMcQBVJ4hKpCFugEnOCXql5m2aXbUXmWudYgElJYz/J91BYG7Fx6BFGeARXT/Vasb@ApSgxpO8CfNQxC@SSPVg3SrkPaXR6hQa4KlZ4HyDCeOx7JAalceoRHwkhqh56c2RsQoMxS0iNAAJRBEYDtOttgyyl2bafT5bFysRvcsYiaJYzwjJaE0RBaCw8mhpHLGM7mCkQGHirVYqKGTSvuGALhMPhSWgXGExidbCgJ0THMB4MCWHQcX6GiscePx7mqVOxWilGJED7qVkOFaGNNULcSAGDhYOyTVknOMCedxsp@NEl2gPE0ZReoTiXDOFAbD8uh9UaS4P/BRIsUOVVV5FHGAoj64q3CBJRBZEQ7r0MTtcPp@bUUizJvQt5NyhQpmYlGmGfDTzTS9WTyLN5Iv0iEel0lvIc@NhQSdDt9SI9BbzbAm75QAwFnBuL4Hb8DBpnTQRDGjmJBUewuhW7bHgwqaG0wVFejLOspjNaOXCgftFMxv8JwE2EhhR@KhaFRqYmBCkJEOgs0602a1fy@65BGETqdjVstSc@bL3H9KTzbA@fKIN1gPBXamRjLEVe4hpRP@sAcrvTM53FxEbLpwQg5xE2GWecaqc7JrzOFK/HDyUknApeiSJRhGEoaiONm1@pBlk4si6FWC7@UzZ6DJDJokhqL5zbQVWffhj7D8bPiTrHslX1hZ09RKaXqtkG6FccmEyi82JFGKaErghTCde0Li49wlYlzrz7Lr2ZAeswAZsc/QGwJO3s825oD7wwPBb81@KxxYzETi7ugjFK3v8v6gtLAGn3PdTN5eG/YpeHE8EvPe0mMS/2RHx5qp1OWYNcilgstk59sS@LRtujIpSRO31foZLiGk@l9BWSw8CwmGkFitS4hhKpL2McA0zTDQ6LYiqG0j6gDoLYHLQu1vgReCU9PV1AfmmJC0xMM3mGfsOW8RNrxSJ@AOP4PMLDqK5PQwQ@iYjn8oAUVo/HJCeAr0Dp7LfBLoBIkTn4YP6RuNJMGpDF5swUBDjsdSqvCeLMILYWYBVsH12cHRV8Az1XI4YycLChyGsCm5ZTMQUfxp6NzapeIl5TYbUgZhhAEqgEKigrbhs81dwqVLVdXVxppDRp4tmb5qDvYx/sQs/1zG0RYNxtYvb649sXGO7vEfYRjk8p1h@P1mZtDurVy/fGIfyWpjeeY3w5sz1KSbT@JfeAl8Mr@eY9UMqCyBJ/oZt8mXdqmQuurviCzfD1zHZJZCclMLSZvEAhjCGaYGWXMDADLNM2LTPuqVRYel9TuADhUlhU6okI/L7T0/NBk99tRCDegTc@hvdm9MN2ui6KHzCdgx0nzEoYhR6FV2Pv2ECI51hXb8jxjpJB/CkMjnSojkm7YCHp38gEj9Cbsmuu9soe1UX0i@jCKDn1XtN7qoUIG6fpuoFzdGPoPuf8Q/IfcfzhONEy2NqxzyQudbrA4SNyoXykMiWBGYZgbri1t7EOQQS5mOgeBIUcTbjfwMysUO8Q3t0E9VkLCAJogJYUKakesndUd37paqqez50DTMiECahxA1@qE06tWZEbsdy@7fdefcHJQ/RB0PiLf6GR2BDVwWsEyRhVEhMHxZaOWmvOexqdheL8vCgwQUNwCT5QAtgLFTpUj/bDkCYRTk8c45hmriczUScgSXsINpCKOeo7YOKB6DBC6R0WCbIIPC1uO0AwvmMArDy/RDcOqdHUJKbpN1pOAyammwllKmSoplitVDbMJaEeptDJdlNAfqqI25RUr5o2o/3j2Fz46@21oF7NzTwTL@4WyFG8q1hCVelqiuRBWWbUSq1fIQXbJ6FoedFB7XAwVnTIks5QNRxM8HSwCV0arxCrfTPH6ofMksiOXIlIYVSpQxFGFN0veLkKUcoRH0XwRbRQSgojPGQjAyM2MZolow3i0YaXCGQcbzol2FcvkkDI55FF46OGcTNZFNBgkRepOsXrqqOUOBCoZ4Om8t0SNrjLzjUtU28u@Qq00MHgK0xzzHKICQUMoSSOdmfWZqddimY4xrSkASIi3ALT4RTQlaZrh6Wpki3gUR2XIo7hNkAHnFUBgxILLXPOYEhEZDXVBrpfT1A9A25XTNUnWca8Y/eX4T86EjuFPv@2YmwypTzrmMlN//yCOdcRsrIHGhAw9t4IMGQcsW6SIBcSSK5cpM4RncM@GNw1nm123me0ZuO8CrySP7h9OheMBUrX4pO8GRuCurJT4IMgm@nopgrPYJRB8DGCfOy4MNeKaDW2uidFJosJJ0z13bN/K4I3HXAS3aJcAV2UuxeVeYXR9SRJThXxYiqA5AaHo2mjgbVmNhuJb3XaqFKkNRauGdJhMSjieBVMsPvAhAfSwr7h43XuQuh8mqv0U0U5t80I57AvPJCSyxYBZmSDPg28HRBXmu@ORIOnjQ9G4GSiki77j9txzEO9Q1ybGngJ/MIaNGTL6fcpLhhk4RC3FlKNSc1DMjJESUT/76Kjss7xipKL4@UkAE8jIMG8ax4hZb0ZyjbnJ8Whheicfn9@TeH5P7s4vjaqn88yH2hXu@XFJLytjCBBwnI3l@7OREaqtb2VnIiuRMwpQPMKDs9iifU0tzOkWBN0SwbU20EcmsvmkcEdk/PN5@L@7AsPoew@tPgMvDzwZAb/p4fY5ha4y8MMVRAWCH6SQ99xOLiLt3QemBWHxgoh9lBVAXiXG5aA2J2iYfRhG@3K0giIA30PzuH3pFt3TnqYK95yRJ@8ywy7y86tot9GyusbIaikiZCYGNyzxMYzMiF89rODI6IjpuXxQp0AnlYqrgkak80ClOSRjZC5jisBvheFB7Ih6aOabcngwH3/of4s145Rdhc8@g8CfTCZIZzyp@O@P@iOuBbPLb7YRfJT3P7wm8VTt/QgBPIjND5lxsqm72OexEhXpAT1CFFabLDLpuwq7LbfXv12HH4ei@0sKlRuLVAlreUJP97wat@@q8RhVhDTJ13seRpL3Ed2DaS5GahzYmIXtfFwXcgsybnowTSUOkbvcWWOuc4snoBvNuzlzepXGDIYaxSROF9g0rib5IiXhEPgAvjiB9Dl8EeC5FTQ4QYVlwzkqcTUMI5@e0Y9JLcIFpHGAEsNieBsDZSMWSgrNEPz6JkrTnJumeStNcyLNqAVMJhkLJJkTSYpawOq5qwq6VjuYw53RCwfJ8LmLbcPjuIaH0xLXSTtZsjMseZksAUNOWsnSngJMOdlKlnbJ4CdLJ2S4SJY@A8O4bSXfJ0ths8AAHljJ8ATdBQtHu5ks7SipGynACzPCdLVkKapTCLPJrYQRQAWWG6RGXDJzXFHMwLOgYyOhMsOQYvwMjpNowiVDvxz8c834/AYX8MQ5yyUKzNJMn@g0Yj0GTwe6jVBn6oyWXBK9@d7hPm0aGl89AP5pGMzF4xB4EMMTyUlmxDOGvrRCAV/IIPLN0uwcMX3yfooHZEekDhRKlTyZPmFPI3mgpZB/DQLXU5PXHoj4YX1NguAV@LB8YuR5@byVnTA5yhGusaZmZAuR@iZ5R6Gwrqfu9OC1H68hmrueDISXbYZBeC0R2BhPBxmOFtswsb7bnyQS8sWtgHY8Ds2@8UaJ1DsVjbiCaJlzvMlZlAwZQ7zxp@4qTiweZm2CBaFnLVfnrSzqF4gXo9eY18UkVd74IAsxngMt3DIvLCTbXWGkcJzdZKivmNcNhXF5ksS5JtkkRNZQPcjACHjq0eB1D5WGfNzwNYw5xEkVBQHEYkapcP7qfoT87nL5PRSoQyRMJTBLsJ7dld4Wr@/sZady3h0ne7sC0TPDdlMzhaMohTHKYXQQk8zvorVbIj5u4eBCPk80gj4l7Ydoi8YE9@BtemzBYaGU4F1OOl7kwfEiPx9RtyWS7qUWCi0apiTg8IJHOR0X7e688oLPqmL0oYlso/vRFexNVnC88hAeFcCbQjlv5Xi6E9e2xm2bFNKiC7JUvcQ4I6flz6iax47A7mkpNlqGBYfDxvHu4YtnX0Knu7a2lhJ99GicP2y1OKka9eMcMm1YjvqDGcOWfAYVsuPiNc670@W1C2eOfIuXcGYNwgBeRBOSn2jjKcHLYvx8qu1CPB42hlEB62LcDIwJroSijoFdti3wGgBCrEBZMgSQULwFfGdotJbCOVmgDrzTrtGg7qvRwM1IjYboxbBqwhXu1C8SC9mB79GtoVxd9JUk0UlstnvIXj3dOmWnT/fY/sudz9iXhy/Zq60Xp3iW@ejl9rODHQa/vRcne2w8o4APXqGBA0rA665lWr0msOx8LrfCCPKO2x9xvqPspLj7idFjT13TwvWoDd/oPelwi@ZYQZXH2oPh6AjnMG26paVnBwG/fs4EcCTctOhEG@77ZxC2CWPaHo55e27LbtsQVsKxb9@2/PDgFevaUIPAb8OTkxkuJOF1HrQViK5yo1v48Bo3CI@LNADG8MfXBto@j2C1NCYQFz0fjcHTvePnJ2zrxS7bOXyxe3B6cPjihO0fHoP16MuDF58CPg9OTo8Ptl@iFwV8frh7sH@ws0UOPAM5jeFpdbqX764saBicsGJe4BI33QIc2eKzzhAMJHh2ZdDZPp8lBw5yH9vo2u@sVrIs4UU//DwhrQmw6Jo9Zr3FpcxwzZf2E8gvfbqqZjHHNig1aCxVaG9l0Vyh20Ol4bjw0BsxvLLIKtMhcoXM46uQaFNOy7aYvIN7TnDum581p7YcgoaEFgA2ggo3oFQYaeBPJjMbBLIKqZldFxWk8dT4pkBhwahPwq0jZYkwJva@IFA8DnDg4HyQXo4cgO7BIS@SDTwegC1HDjwAW@EOKIoe4F4QVhAhBsHhANkzW@UOX/X6@7T@y9Yih22DRrFFkSdeb1SlBhvfLm73@l26Q4HP8tDVSIZv2jZF8Sk83kHQ7Yb3EzYtIHngieI2KdyrBiFlYDZtXGoQ29icATVs8AVqwH0/RjvwmVJJaewUN/tYjs0vpzjvGg7f0jTeikO0x4qoR6QiNm/b0a0PdMCi7xIB4k0sk/mI4u0KqdB6aDyIuX0rRUPseaSbg8ItZfdlYPtWBn4ZMABInRjpmNRT0RFPBOO2BSkrvgsUifO2X8fDAzm3BqY1ESG8PfIr@927lEByZmKcFO47pNxBFeFFmxm@Ztl2PWjjxFZ7eFwFuaDZcfuBzetQmSzB@O4vCI0dG6T2plKdSI3u@5xK0XGdWKJNoOI5qTaBKB@SKlE8XySP2FfY1qPLx2gfHWbHaLqXVmztLIOLSFcWTr@AIMwvTsTehi7CFfKnNOYdX9NllsVKdXf7TP36TQavTuBsgV8XFm4i5Jdf9jAtaB60zkcbED2Uu0RLC@/f8AdNjC321Aluia08BAbjwI4N47onjXLkx7cP33bHsyjT7uT4/n2Fx1KRM3GOPPA7ypi7ZVgtTDJDcepM7PWI8U7ILPB6JXTJEMyIXz/BYydYC2XAiIN8hK6tnbz3QrCQsHTNQRs4i7jZSlR3BD/FqrR1IhQk6VHi9ZF9rWxX0tVUdrxzhMXQqYQsOhNCxouvxvtPqL@6BW73bnDAvx8Ornhn7nj38FHQdu@E9lF5U9PzYfFuKQbr4WC/vgMs79x@KbBQ9sx8wLyTvA0tovSIODOLiWh37N0pvrlVd9T2AAz2vTiDEgGNpTZwaIk61GKq8AipOJixQHRyurt3fMxkPj6BuMD3cMjQEmwQYS/wa0H47lnbIWanRUJTNFiOhKfQZWLrWnTe447GPBN5c1iFkEEyAh8Rs5i8hJO4nuhZSISg3fTEEEPMTebuOuRBfk0AvkG1tcC8EmMxLCqgNLOYCd752H58U7fAW4bLxvE9@bRjmvfdeJ2WN4oDim/@Mc7xpMjs@nvF5eNSmA4XsKy3AypwCyRpvFFWYyeQcB8CatpkDd5RLWGV4qZ5LmAnQtzhDq/cpIT99ycoIiQuhHNZOMbWhXAsssbl48VQzKGdh9gNGLilU3jyHcrgEbJ4ctmIV2hq3Okpk10QCJl40dOTOFVA9PpNObobVhn3k5VIII@3tUXKTS3MZR1nZwXs8vxAn@De5tVp9jCdFHDbO5NSfzVJ8V5iIqUQ5zMLE3oC5NVCYfk@2NOlCKOrf1/YvA@Z5p9Brw/j@zFIf@TT9D5Q7sGLTOg/JoA7UMe3yocNZioiiDoz@pSJslNnFM8f5IXPC0FmUDGw2cFrrSZTTbHhVN5mQ@c9Uhw6BblVhlgTjgrKW80t7N/cnRwy5HvTW/j49Hhjw0C4R/DmF9HhupiulZgTni2ddLM8z6Fg/FhSz8XjY3Qa6c4zc3Rojm9o5YVBT1pmixegLQ4Z8W21mXCKgRKhWUUNr8HDSb3y9KyeqpfjJdw/eLbHlkhFXXtiClL25FSM5SzYzl0ZINZL0xHYa9BRvE/8EvwgD5kQJKCJDuUphJvUvXkjjICwXKMbF8S2T8FS9elKb/um4aDij4xMN0g/hog0@bp3uJ@aNaGeK0/Eh8z5fUeBWBlZ1WSKCm44j4uQJkHw2kT3WD8l4Y0DYoPkHZfmGlm9mFtdl6h0TibI9Grr9cySWZEZ9LmG0/MH3lXr4tztXLZZl/W/ag7N0bu3jBVW2DLelPWYq@LUVyt4tFVhqFWkyNZzRLAig5ukVvRMZkwjjYq4nszGw@/yAkuRgcbKJTwBMUWlbKkXUiGelAsqvdpqveJUcuVezamX8axekK4EaT2toMNj6DyBtfAF@VpQx670F/HZVsu5ZN6gOYJRUnT2g9HZD@zfcYZL7Nmm@XLaZiw9ws1qeIZEc6wrJboQHClTQvlHekSHeHQ8Ik7TxTjb0rIhB4D9DAir/pDeo5T0KKcN@oFLPiIhFUmIvbffS4/CU0c5mjCAIDW7HmZng@CMwyi47sNdR3w3tKpzaUzHo46pGIgaxiRuJ5/JMh4BxIyKo1e1uuRrlmF2MBN49eN7isY2Nvid8DfgTZN0uFPD8OjgQ66ORlzfgE@fFhMwCRLMfTq@IUHx0a6jgbvQFFRA511oo7tEgiD64DZudk3HkSj@BiCAI/4RF6k0MYMpBCuQE/lRP5o7QF1zk@N6XEXAU5C8Uh5hYRE2T68yBk47vglHmKxAE7g/ukJ0clzBI0qg6mS7VYwofIoHJ5TQMrSw@YhLqlLyquKnO46mxKKpYbQwcAwVj@7FBk5kwejnuQXNZ8R2rG4XMs1x8WiMDjTScVyRfjpK369hmvUo89xfveWvTvhr3J9nahxKg/57HKgUDyQnrsfhbpg8Dpa5lVaFkWyiQU2bGkgc47Dlu8L6WuA27HHgalSVnCojj40JDzXm83pG7XOfhYk4EYFH/jXuL@g7L2o@yuVE2CeT6eNXEhVk0d5YsZVkiko1x@5u8s4p8kEykwGbjPHoWN9EdrxRiiOTgp2AgIbT@NRsq5UxlLQechxqM3J144msCWFiU5nOBj90eKthzWgjMSxRmmlC3JDOF0I65L0QA0EwkdBY2HKrYeSRiDyKgcVQC2Gy/NDirQYORZtu4hU8xvgeX2Fjn8xcGC4x2/MRz/mQF54fRp5EEDHdBXk2mia5CR774I6iUHf0IuO0R9MQZzOJF7FJ3ihNix@ZbuMs90LEJ@KMIuQUt/Ae@QhMjwPoIfnOq0L0vJF@kV2SPjVAhO53rSHbwlGEQaeppInz6Khr1Uf9SKSuxR/0@11cVCTB7opOPAvdHfkCrqaMIcaW0TTpADfu8PAZNInz4xBJY4cI@Qr3f4w9/ME5XkiN6zaoFglYK06o2IEmbTkjPl8BbWY5z0@FW2zg80VRGMyfxzPBa463HsS03zdMS5NAFvNBypF4Udu8fYvpcjwWghq6oEsrSdK3B7Z5sfMpLteu6bllPYayS7Ham9OWV8YHpQBJoUc@B@JqQV@RpNjSr8mXflUEmGHPsKP/HGjTusRrj6Ut6DEooA/CqW95l1ZLk6RjK1rjRbhIyrjwiMem3YFn8rkbkK3wumQ87etn@GoXUBh@sX/mq8EmLYVlJFyTGi8mQ1Vf2i1EYHigpO3i4i@tR@Cpfo4PjNSzAkDKUopNZomWlkVeSHbp4TwTYAPVksSWHiI0OG5gm1AzNFEldQEUX@UYJ8Yvd4/lBNIzuwYe8tVmZQBPv4wxEGYgXCm6Kw@SWBP/qDwwUbBwCd0IayYL3M@ltgLN3fJs4L5jBFOtULRY3qGCT58enLCTw/3TV1vHewzMR8eHnx/s7u2y7S9pCRvXwUkfLHt6@Ay4S7RYzhfFD8FB3jqBmDJ5SFsvvmR7Xxwd752csMNjdvD86NkBQAPwx1svTg/2TjLs4MXOs5e7tLgOENiLw1P27OD5wSkEOz3MUKphNGkcjx3us@d7xztPwbq1ffDs4PRLSnH/4PQFJoaL9lvsaOv49GDn5bOtY3b08vjo8GSPYcGk3YOTnWdbB8/3djVIH9Jke5/vvThlJ0@3nj2bKujhqxd7x4z2AMRKub0HudzahqEqpkTl3D043ts5xQKNTTuAPMjgsww7OdrbOUDD3hd7UJyt4y8zAujJ3rdfQiDwZLtbz7c@hcJJyj1YgXrZeXm89xwzDZg4ebl9cnpw@vJ0j316eLhLuD7ZO/78YGfvpMykZ4cnhLCX/297V7rdxrGcfwtP0RpIxAyJnbvAoc3VomNZjkRZVkhecAAMQNggAGMGIiCZOSf5kRfIA@RR8iOPch8kqa17egBQpJfYvvdcn2NxMNNrdXV1VXX116@P8grvlqKqoQygFnyH5/03r0@Ibidfn8Ka8eYbDGfwYJDfAmGglXuQ9ZAIjFEO2Fsg0stX77BUpAMNQF69fX4E718hTYlae0gFDJg4OLWTQYVAxFO7m@rroy@@Ovni6OuDI/z8Eot5e/L6yIMBO3mNCU4w3uIdsA5U@oZ6jeME7eJHYNaM5tw8Dac6OVZ7h9@eYMslNXDA6xPhFiLbwXOhOczlUsZylnQH6BsIrm0HSnv@1fsQ8RznPS@LfTEG4Ojg5eERrMgCIuUkH97AqrM1g3xkf4OVxnyEnymEmVbYGHfq3X57gGdFTTZ2cFxHnTzer@GBea7OM5@4YkX8KJQhm63Xv92rg6H7ul738g/JmWrGfTnEy/2pVJ70ETHg0fJGB8@zZ0z3nRShdpdkH5Pi8HB/AVMy9Zc4si24Dj1VKrVCyYaH8LFg7SKKeFcEQaNRNNJZRrxzIqmSPBD0uyvsQBldXXyxWUc3KAY@UqJBBP/0f0p@8OJgvQDpzG6tUgmNWGpG90Ooq@FKCNqA/hFkgW6bqixGYfhDxy3b1aHNX@wMBi3X83QeShuDHdhxvXuyN8LOTPbCbH5qLO0qC5p8pO1uUmHM9rKQTMm4FEfUMxf/qcf0x9OtYewGdIpSVeSLFueku8TZMeAorwSiAk9P0CCjzvdi77uTt2jNlatrtZn3z817nlsYDoh4tLDgnVG@C/rz/IITwAQjTA0gSVeQLkolK48OJzGJbyDhFSYiuH1aq69CWteBJKDIjoOeXSeuxqPuxG49yOEvXu292H9zfAyiE1u7trW@uVHLGJSs7/L89x3WQzipBBI2hHUc9DT6ZM2SA1B8aKZYyNoJ@xMDl0qYELHL9aDRS8RrMGEZ6UAlFGTY3QgvYOljBJ4TIh0cRUAajzOaXxfOTGEAN9VVD3tzHUxIxQ9AVyIekFiV3pRGbYL/YNlm@uspbjokDCQsRui0wLlgXZDcc451JCgZN4Szg0mKjuZjRl0zNCBXF4XH4uFZ@iW8bY1ixJGKOF9p2CknNOLxbCuUDpvo88z@hvBCxNFLYF/w5jvhN3h8J3h0hE4XRPFe/BrIeGxyoj86cTpLp8@k5ItdH4ZoacnUtKPQm@9Jo2juidvYAHxYs4GacoExg76aKbhm8EBmq6QA189znvrInIogHFhOTThWfgPnLuqOlFLTOCDyW6NLKC7LgJUw1W5MHRmd5J3Bo9DkTJHpV9GDyv8DabKg/B2wOKH0hFoWZt@DKEmlMq3AfCWidG/0hoK1i5FQ0371Linm1h6YK9Mx2aWZ8PEZIIGMzlS/eEcohW13AQGQydGxYc9fE3F2FYDp9LnjSXbcD@k3r4eukrVCLxVz5RY2LvKkduX1Hgr@8JTHviarwq8gq/qcDbcGzXowmWZMefU0crg4T@N4lJbJAWImPHHpFQelznJWWWaZlgMCmWQtOC2DfARq6e2du3PLykK0TMl@2eHShIKid7E98/0kNPOB4ujbNEAio6efEmgdAmqjmYyLjyDMNSjOshdiOU9b5AzBq2HjG1wgelw6IeslpSn3KcWBYCVJUGECC4ji1isCaWlZvTGtJ88kcqhp/Zs@Y9KH7NXSKYqM3yEttE/DF9WLYApN7j2s28xipeXXgzyGJmJl7JaQ/HgNbnMwGIHqGGC/oY357tQrqrfidAj70XgkcIOwnnVH4pHQSj9Ug2oTW@@0zDACOjUt6sZ4GKFVJP6gLl2HGADK6COTwoZygXk1j@5qp2N3slJR7k7yZQdoQiiiRMQdtaF@@olTMUEF4TMkCnYjY1xQSCbVg/sOZvrdDEY/4NqPKlC/FbYMkKhVJPkCeZBO@gTJ2Iy568NBRB4NGAr0gBhKVNiRZuJQYY3eFHaSsCUnAbNEqFHqyc@vxzCpDoaCihLGldqB@TYKMJhIpaogeRpsz0p1nZqyyOC6vdMYI3DP9Pa0cs77RqQ8YyXCf6pVR3xiuWme3uGTOPn9pxHOHniDe9migmKDUWfF/dN5OUftQ2C@t91w1LJ9oqDJtIIhut/I9Bn0iRe161Dg@5pBHIVTsACape6kRGXU3S8HV/36waAXdLqDbgB2GsKhT1ji4eOUHnHAOqPBTUTX59CHlpWoNU2eGT6G4dTwt9mXrFkQW1EcDl07HCEeTfeuGAWCPOcY46fMekX8PZzFOjN51taTTJn08VIKt6t4tTvzrlYWZeadeyxABNzuTKQEHxGN6dyRdba0Npeg8akEVhsbqqAC746AvFSLt4FEtA2TarFuzFz4gd0JtMzubPFZa5JvEZbgCHGUwsMQL6CJXHqdD/AqVZAin2FEwDNV2SpbWXkXZYJ4gvgwvZvc1c0/uPXQgF/R/MrqIm5ZxAgk4toaTClie0VAQaEtFP3XJRlNkhikWLcDq1AvVWh9Mltq@vP0LmpQhA8oRQKXN8eVOCNdMHzwxjW3DiKnPvVwUcmpnEewHKiC7MVu@W6GDe8Lj6XJj5u47DlDwXQgJbtWo@8iVROohDdpzkTP2k1mCOT7Z0y1@tBRmyGgvyiizLrtwXW05kIHTLq8vuK21mAEwtiZoZ6EeuSieDDMPZB6d8qOhQhri2jd9Lx743yZ2XxYLJdbRFp/io/TWma2PTNMk6YYRZQBD6H5Ss@GzWeJOPHrON/8@vQeOtxFsyQ@yiwqZrxbPPdxUXyPAbt6oTFTitqOYKM18/6sDh2v3y1BpEw2r@okMeooMupTfrSKmiGTodLDKUTcJ22foUcLKIf1toB29vjcSdTZYDgNXao/pcAqkZ6Is45nMkEuDdsYfIEocKzhGiFlFM5JfkpbeZVCA8GC8QMXiFpxWEj8UOzBTQZrho8IzL/t1jFaqIKSCJ527QgHg9FvCEYg@uLckYiH@rRQuahxSRNTElgVlOpTJenj5PDzrD6hUuZIAVN8ASlMj@Zk09XDe/Vr@wLpoATOTZ8lkLecx854agVaA//Yn@oT1IGTqiRnakalJ0KdRAPMBbBSOr2QzVXU/roj5niMbpBpBAYEv3bxz4rkQPTtjbKhNmaZtKaYxBNy82zzVGGXsyQMxb@R/DIVWdUlwxUKCLnFkN@vQAkIT0qtx00BQtaxOS/VUBkjyOhXcFrCS0I3TeI5F3xHokqCtXUrRXlRim27jMLCQkCxWJwmaQjoLIuTJKXAQrewLVaKzcX9SVKAQqx5nykOQyGjkqahGTkmIDxSa41EOauofFk4mD6urXupj4a/6et22fpanv0K9DEtPCtUZr9ulVNfU9VWq@msqZxAD8@uNfURSOHZDTZS4df9RydPbOhyExNqGRkpLUPisPtoSt2g3Vb8PlI7dOZa6xi6PPvgtza/6nwjSgpc/dNA6kpg@mu/vrM6MFU3RJD9CXVOH2Vx2R4khdXBlR57hYauxtEz8APapB201benx8cpUNfGVMcZXYej9XK5jDzcsDHsdQg1epK6g1I6dak97vVKw5svR982SiT68ZL6XjR4pg3oEEYE5kRUHIw6fI8DtgGSYuqCHFNFU3/cbtsXJuAGJY4djBqnFKwDRetP18S8fHtK/h8qUtbXS@wg9u9Smcl3E7CeKaXoXSjIjRHB7x29eQbkwRdtDMM2G1VUGMplHcwEy5bn737EBQTvIaHBIhRi72MSnew8D3u9QV69HYx6LcQBeHQ7m@H42M5Q5iS4wUhnd8cRoc3mVfi@27NODWMSm9WxOL0u6VshNLw7Qty/CjtHk6HrnP3FgVUFuryC3VxBmOm8cjqOJ5jvDyiW@RCa/aDU18HQbRKdZhPDSi8TOHmCFq1W8gtNn1QSj1xiQrP7UyNRFze3SFAM0HWPVAENSU/DSz25I7khrnM@qbSRhmUuQ9qEiCoPy4EHyf44qfg@brcfJhQJzZ8H9ncXiLQFQDNQph/QE8Gw/6kA0/p4Bi6E9Ru8c2Ne7mCGOmbIZJ42/R9v3L29PfVkuLKi9vb24aFQUHv7e@oQX@zvq0P4vY@/l/zq@nqNZe6h9xFe7uuXt2ofyiAH50rzanQIP@Gbj6fCMFgbh/hJyX@Srz2p@zu7tah0trePh/bh6a//9h9//ff/LO3Jj//CH/v04@wvJlGxWCw9aX58snRbw99nhxe5J42zJ8OLXKeGXIbi/s0oCnqBFT1abGbuOSHV6nUbd52aMtEz3YhCNTFc0oV/fB8ssJ9@4qfzOHkcJY@IiZpkD3rDq4CyKyph18/t5ZaW4GnHz/1Ljnwn8j4w7z/Ae@WhLCfQBCIt3vuj9l4fnJzYsOMo9Ul7b4eIkYP3XApejmxcXWb1LYGFM1UsqouCujTNwzCPOidMN5HNTG7Mv0ojde8oJof2rsVswE1pcn2zO543pq6jDul32nXOl58FYqk8bT3jPTQqYwUEHqavcay6nHvF7kNzcdvLL5xVNtYvCtlsNmMuRKs3ScxRbUOqy1yQpbfQCZ@Bj2ENYcpA3@mCOh9pAQUiMbJZui5rqcnXurl9NK3JYmKDO5uz9Hn0N1FHMkbMsYebwRRQx0KDj64gU9GYTmGgbjB96B4eNICO1@2Q4FJ8SXI0DJvd9tSEPOCNFEntsFbikbll1Z47MaecUcORfj1uJwUCQVALIKweLHS2QCbeANJ2SdpxH/VvUDfmmepSwL/VGg2wCQgaDnrTTg8qcymUKroB6QSU92Swen19lA5r4JyNELSeUGY0D1gSy4vtboToiug3cYcM74fqISYXK3y8/UtolDAfUMOR@@HaeBTE7fU5gGjQhkdY8PEUHW9hERuu4JIqDIVGLRrH@n45kQPLQ89TQ06JVIXfyeY7sQe5IMkelovuBCaEd2OGnuTEtzvCaUO82g8NacEG9WQmOTRXzO4baJXXuFeJ@5RAFExZpLvEQDRM1WWvf2n6z7ubEV5HWHR0lVxNleMTQGKZavRxeaqOzwI47Fylm8dwh1PuyR5EUbcBxIIuyjARBCIfHhhBqee5DFcm3ILbgUhgfLU8NDPK7p9mpXAypPP53N5H6Nrtay5IJcQNUtwTC3HvDjEOBiLy4Fd/0C@QyG2EcbfJAZRc@2Mti4e4L07blNSwuysC4yHAfpoBphrONbqQbBfTUCflEJ3wsALO/yujegdEM3HzioiWgyPQIMMcZnTOEyIlJRpOoALSRJE2Uvy3UPBRijF7Yacbp/LkBYGBw865F7ea9DjJL7HBNnVnKIsHJfROsxEJl0JvHZqBgld/A0G75cnh50W8pzuDqxpfPGlycpfoPN3WPH8YeaSbY7caZjCQD6dvPj1CtLjiWkcgcgjl2UqzqkpG4ZM1UOHSRJYXy3TAhwoQaTFLk8IZUKM6Qw0QpzPTIJHC5VTxFgMjc9srOcmoGfLycLFKMCe8Nb/oliIT3GbMkZ6P/9/1poayMcLzyTD5IBXyAazRScCJwdGYLXLhDLwJtaIu4HggGkdjRKTjQBZZURDCpsuT1KrUtGOmKt11GeECaUpDwkeBn2c5eyxnsur@Jrkv0rkLOT7S9VEf7HItTWfoyXkv@fqIF/PKxroul09s0dYb/brVR8vkZJYJmNCjIySn5TVoI3kwIIbuWDKDc7uINbQNr6W87rNoFqBcpgqnsmiLRtLZMUELiMSxCnvjeHAS//Y6PWFLy16feUnXrYJeEIAaLCpC4JXkCR4x@tj7rcwClANdEAQcvxZEITxnMqx5iIXpvIg6@4OJW86fO@dOvrKx7TlkJxs9LNuMwDLKNkNGS8MrG8X2JFRG8mu/D1mEjxrdVivsayxWyCq1mU91KfYM3fkfjbiL@IZbh4R46FiyPCrAINILoTU9D0dB5zqgx68Hp6NgegKLEP182efxfI3lvYLFCO9koi@veI7utUDVcG7RTk544kFdpKioADSfZkyqASPxWerCAgKEcwTgOk3/o3RnLTLY/WffhdGead2EQb1kDSXiIOpL3ji5zPCFv9d4I22d3wFvutaNwPJIn2auqRYdAT/oAGHrLedgVb@HOz1hP7UPoaGDhfH42mjOlVc9YNCyNrk@3ZUBx0NfmtZHl2LYxM2r@vW4F3elZ3Pd0v3CTLN3H5M5qa@rvuP@Y3IZztLO6geWe9aFWZrYMiSoEiqIEaZLsexHTW7qP7kdE6VBTBWG/aiuEX@Ub2ufGBvW7ne1qYGoHNaGjTZOsZ8Zy9yA3LVMss4q0@vHKeMD2wFEwWYsD@niaRLNt/YY4wgjbggJEzO4v4fN/rds5PIb2m1IqKTtUgnPZBmW2Pp0qiCvyrKJbVm1wCl88/jgOhTLVswJy3i1bo1jMM0/3GC9x3JLaX8WqXTUtq27PE5NtJRyqOM1LXIaJYZWZnsUqK@2MmJrEiRyhgKMwHSWkm75VPpCscFGCaTkNs8q2VpjMj1dIN6giLnFM2/UiLlPntbejAZESYGnWlqoyuqWLGwS74tevWQF021N65S2yq6SBTTRWRcY4YYN7iVUOE@oyi8jFLdrEZ34y29GpjQB0lS6zWQWsa8RHRKaZc91c4JoTi4R4R4bRXimjAWKbqOHoIFJw2aLgwHUmv22VoaX1V4HxGJaF@bA8CB5x1YPG5DRzJFx44jjYwjjEYLqZkG7ysD/CHAMUuoaHTopDwiorKWMSUTnw5AaRG/jjRDIAlXKehmJGSpl@ZqgymbFo0oeUBOewP0V6j2LQdyKac8dfsMFhVSOZVWXA4T3r3601t3hlk71b6FLGiRy4pRm8bw8HOKhgvu81KWsQFm4CopXnvqFDmrylVR5DUI/TymbeQRNYE0DMfWgMsq9Ig7eKIRuGEROducmYVhsH2pH95/J/61prGMVhAOMglDW2gHqZ3QFNA@waAh0kJUmaO5plANSm7MzC2tJVDVSF4m0KU7WK3hFluqFDiEzKrRKRyq5QXUUW17FhV5T7SFS2YXZlIsQo@jNoK2jsImOcOOlijzLHyxuhxKULTdyQ7P4oKQpMiWu7O4sLSlpG7msZ3SMhYZ@ilDcjhQxzvty3mKGdUEI4UsivCwpME2M1jdc6H/gBJIimZ1LixURFK@JHpJ4aEoJ3cd9Q/nF1KGsn6IPHYYYzJw3IpqQRDXYL0lrMj@XoLP0vIdJyaH3t8OlP2skHsqqcm/3XbzIa/Fmhddie@2ZRiX0NuDqg3@7TT7nSwdLk/VHLduHrx/x@ktuCviHGZTOK8QGRACkfRR7ctf4o8SuK0Zxna9NN@IX7TgJuWu1YDkGYUsHmvJgJ8YUg6QsOusAWwIY@FkLpjbSuXoRhWBiYlNmLTPJndhligwzy/zVqAREqbYc434ExVF4EZ3kxK2rQZNxAWCBwu9tQgUgu7bCZhEaRJzxDH/KmcpHbYYpbMtM5h6o5bpUK32Q9lAnWMfaHwXxg1SsZEuOA/ZVH0GiQMua5cOomFEnP18le4hetvxgvSy7TD7t5UQ9W84OQbdY/YVl/L56WuKghXIc03IHJyo58MnkABLDAPUwwjhx5ovUsrfcfrna9w/15c@6MCz/6dWXZUP@ZlqJWU6UmOZCJSZJILma6HijfCY9iQeYtn2ykJdF7eH6Bun6YN7o@gYL6@Ob2FWSTjIPqFp8vaDa@GYgOQyjSoXkf1xYEcpantOXjsztS@XOT2ge72QZXv3HMvz3vQyXDC0QbfSelcYa@n@M/d/D2CN@ZW@rvFWu/2b7vuadYzOWM7PfqpTzWFV2P9s8nxyWzyfbay9/zMbZ3Wrp7Qj@xtkfsxtbWX6EB/i1qn@9z@5mdzDZxm12WvJ9Hx6llL1jKGX3S1MmppruwD@767rcjWl2t@BT9p@yuxvwUKlWoSXnk6Pt88lWGf93an8m9cPeXTHKx12lDgnTRhYE3guUEHkyywdRUuSBtTqcIAtoczztIMWVHwotUIMxeGZS3SqLrgIMxOAP70O5f0vDZoj@SPgxMSGa8IkLDfsgsXqcCWaAqcKDP1QFrfaieiWAExprArWEpNHq8mlxA7euLwWDwjTA4E2Qmsmh3GBeuFQxwpvh393yZ47Bo3jmpEAw0nubsipuyar4v1k1nMZXg351Aap9Vh3AcMWh@j7itkT97nAYxqzxd8J@OCIoE@gOKjp4zV4TLyXsdX/g8L9nunDVpILq30d1PpvDBRWHU@U8@RxmVvearKIPMCv1M@6PbazpXyC48cI2PCejT9d0uvHVuEEXEpyOpifxS0KiKCGoecyoFCXQ5Rql6wADBwjGPwIWgxQgDkbjfokudgOFDc/KIPb@dfADNA0vk4WuteqQDJ39P7h0c2sUDumIy6TdduiapLDXeh0Og1HAiHUYNT8OOuEJIvHAYERXDhpPWfU1Ha6JbWhiYywRxUEPl/uwCoweRrI/yunjn0RapfC4MV3X4@A5dRFCJLudIp2agFwOHy2gK8Lbg0GcpOdT4yYD/UznIDw2GCQ@GoKbg0mPQJpj/1d0I1aUkhfUjuSnVJq8oIqoNSPVxWs0sFdhf3xNvGOutT2rPLsQzDq/Yl0vThGvW8/kSnnHQYLiMImzubKFX8Yce0n7khmBDjD9AMWaWwIJeUDGtFt4DZZCFA0a3xPQEkolmJDIf0X9TaY9hdHDIzq7@2EnIFlx00AwHnjb6kaUAHOWOh9Ad2cS5VOs2hh3oiLPBTpY0Y2icbi@ubVGDaIVXydtDZqppNUSlDwKRtMSNe4qvu6ZXmzHV6oXvg97Er1CzSY4X56UxGd4o1kw7lFYy4ZHrAOkTPUUqOBu5/nd4dHxV3unR4d5UFPWMXlEx5JMWtciLn9eoe/tHiI1MBthFp6@xcbGGjO5G@Vzn6NHjpv@uU32FbvBuoAoKuIa0B26OZ@ySZwFF6yGaLb3O3mzHU5QQxo1GqcbNmVMV004mrh65mezeKQrwrqyyIIpYAPIgx3TJ7dHPRA8c4nulBVAAZFu9Rg4sofyEznX2XlcKJg59YyeCiBYC4VddrI4B70uGJ65V@N@StrmaO4EKgdCDrf/WbQ9zpFcKDo1deWjHV9r@uWaObf33h17H82V1G1shcuEOx3sT/X4uWM5meYAQTyKctZHJv/nv3Ne7TYB0em5sYdXL6gPvkaOLrJQP@K7at1c1ITBiiHbh2IcTuIDRvr045rJ0Bi0pkUC12odgFXdcj/YdQxd7yOs1SsrTd9f9T5ClaMhIoAOQRiGp1CiV8N37dQ7c0SsdH7exwuol/Ho3ncvvnoOQ45xYmEUn/3lYvlJKZ/LeV4NuxD4dL7v8OWLb9DLP/KK5O0/Hg2uhS6jwFRShNG@js7KF9T6vINdK@EsBMnZCWPpfbQ/PQ06X4O25OYCIAGGJdHBOBiU7k4g58tqGJuEOhdezmLTyHfSg@t4Hzs@pboahe0a@ypuI/@92/FqMfy5sqtYhyr8apVKjyGTj1FNM1Tv9mG1fn764is/txMoLNVfMCtyKw3DHMAoxDAuvtrD66hSrANShbgq5tN6xDDw30rO2U33ZacU7OZqt7d3tucrxtMF5SeXMHDLHeeF40b@/JDWRgkXTIehjy94afvi6NTJQ16EYMGXfVzepiS0@BCrr@tgdkNJQUvg9DWm8f21pSV6h1nGke9Xy2UPEVFuobQI74@HYnlijWq3o8BvuYaQwbC74LakarFa4oMsUamyUS2vb342GMES4eOF9EsRiBAfrZb33Xi6BLph6Oubl5ZAT4bV1H@8trz1srv/z99tv944dJuNLytO3vk@orD90dBuwCi4KbJaBDJ2JFi71Ag8udgMSsPgh0FprVVuguZZ2WyFm@vhVnl1q7kerm43tre3m@21rUZrezPYXG82Sgj2TlmK190@aEkOsz9W235YtXcpZlvV8na7XalsbLbWt9vb1fLq6lpja71VXltrb1WC1dWNVnWrsd34tNaWtCcDAlbLXVw7ZiXw07uVu8ycbJfc3v8B)

I downloaded Safari 5 for Windows from [oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/safari-5-0).

This answer uses [JS hack for Safari ≤ 5](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-3e68270c67701bc3a7c9523ed706025e):

```js
var isSafari = /a/.__proto__=='//';
```

Answer (score 3):

## 276. HTML+CSS, no JS (Safari 5), 13000 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退 @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anet     /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._'4o'6o@]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeeee;eecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
(print 164    (exit ) )
  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}












































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  #ata",_"[];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1<PLers 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}Vngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrs94 Cr u Uithw;re-  8hardoc""2:2FAC/'='d  t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")  !@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * *<;
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                 \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*  <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dc@NKdiD4XJj9B/uSAnWLoEiABCVKFClSpc9b6ltVUkuqW/c2xWKBICjiigRYACiRpVJFd8@G1z12zHp6vBNte8e37VnP2jsTMd6JnbUnxo6JsF8nHPPkH1Celw3Hhvsf9J5zMgGCFCmp2u2IfVhIBPLzZObJkydPfp1sGn7n5z9P4MOO3O7ovOsGLLD8gLU8@9LyNLY9Yk8M2y/klyUJQ21554Oe5QR@SUownTHHumIHjmm3wI0F7oXl2O8sD/zyjPU999wzeizoGAFYbIjFdq3u@977gJlur2c4LR9CLjN2ZIBne2BeMKPpB55hBrbrgNcKYy@drtFrtgwGISyv71kBgS8wAGFeUJxJn1XGnrueb2HypuX7LjquMbZh9frBqAqWIoQwPNt9tvXi86nI64x9bkDO@l1rOJUXPcde2ZbXmoqh6@zL0/39adc8@0J1HbZ/O3/6Mnvp@UbXmIa/wrYGgXsQTLsX2Na55Rgsr61r@WnPVbbtGbeirDHPMlptu2tptmMylXWsbt/yGLqwtutBlQVWt5gr5hpb45iaiXGLY88psJXwYYZ37oOne2mB0YKa6NtWi7U9t8cMx7@ClPT13Dg8gl2fJAcTMgiExr7xIXbLYr5j9/tWwD2huJZH3pAy69rOhcSp78hzWwPTds4hnAV47Q8CKpMvmRCtyvqChjU0sARhgQeDLJy4PSteFz4QL@Ta71um3bZNjhxrGFiOD@X1NWZD3V3Z3S5rWV2IMIZuZpjvsoEfc2p2jY5mahIiF1NhvYsus5nZ7zPuBcWALO3niszqud/Y7B34dzs@G/Z7zLd74B2YbrttWeyd1e9AdNZrSS1XYvCY/amSRbZFC8I4FpRu5@hrwFuA6HTakLUWa8bCQT4oz1Riw3EBfR5zjB6nBrM/otIDmChG23U1dG@5lu8kA3blehesaZkGFhsT863ztjHoQop2G6sD6MD2Wc@FL1SiwyBbEDlAXCBsTEyaWRBMJqxeqw8NE6vXRXKBug5r@cozgD48X9RjYPeAOuwg6TPL8G3kWBDFt5wWUUY/4mUulDZe6ezShoYHqBh4BNu3PCJ9gsuwFADSiGhVufLsACgCS7HFjizDY6eeZaU4nVq@afSRSuNJQmIuphBgQTQizI2N5N7hfhIIlMfQjD4QpLd8@t3vSAbTKmyxUYZfRZbL0t6LXXa9eIZmzjOBiPueYqRY5QPzs2dnFvyGejN77t1IAFUCrHRZ1u0HWUPtQwbVADKYNdCIJvUyr/W7sYTZxlQdxJoND9WC2gAmwL7MUMnMgechdx8j1biAQndd5xzwCYX1Bg6v8tUcVAHQX8vPMOvSQhrgdeReEYZPO0Ah8A9BY5yFdziEUOhyoCkKjIbp@m53QOEgph9gewSsQFSEeNBmX7K2YXcxCvgjKJ5rz/KBODHOwGlhzfdsx2ppLMwGcR0P2uIlJGcAUHKA1tCL8RbKFASGinCpqOj18Td@p3V@DnC2TNP1WoJcvwRiN6lrNCiz0LkxJFjXMbqULQiXwdR5dEjg0ujaLeJyhjMSSVAmKNUrd9BtMWqoVzY0uY4BzNYCBmEGFidydxBAHjOsZ1xwjmhzyoWC94wmVCwlQGlTsVX2ZAdqyYRmTjSj9gZBu8jU/h5L@tnXymZJ2Vw4syBzKS21tJjNnpeB4LQlcgJb8i7K@XJroqvwA8N37ZbUHwUd18kz1WSyWXH7lqMkJ2AkM0mvmUxpyKmVVNmumFrbdlpKcgNosQoJJ1Nls2LW7FK9PBU9niSAuUIw2FwtxUzJyGqoUVxmeyBcaMDJvlSFKebn@g1EOXprMWdEzLTbJXdIkOiCdOkigQAf0vyuZfWVnKankE1guJnlRo9ZJZ2CIQpcsuvpZCKZjhedIEBJJwqKjfXUdpFtdfsdlDcAKY7fB57rIe2aBlCPj51aACJdhjWJrqknBM5CPPHKSgLXbgIjDemImiRvchhfRUYpIIyb0GRLtlqxhgxMANpy4N/ixl0XpQPKE/Y8wDocTNQ4h6qByLwgW7wgPCVymSzShQMMBaE1LVZUmzY0AmxuwNMFzcfKBsGX8zwMQOONJMZ7esYIezUuGowbDPZpBusBe/BGzLSQ5wDzsXiHgokMqP35IPcyt81yar5QmGxjt5pY4GW31O8Bk36XvbMlYeHjjQkZDWuDmN01nPOBcQ78wnUgimGaVj8QjApK4gfAiqb7G3JUReep@R1p8cl02tSJhOLROA1k8rz2RFdoIHcRYrsKMhmKfnwswFq2B2wJevKp1CHA5VTi8hsMMpGBN/KcLIQSABCZNbTMQQBcDQj4qmObHaBZzJ3D@SLvhKaTB6d46sDZ1XaUNGZGrz7OS1o2csJszAWhYo3ehgOdK4KqTjhQ5ccd7oZs@L0ZgN0oi9ARxFy1rKEB7d0Ds@c67gyggMgILAaZ9OH1AJLYCQrF0HGFYhc11khSjqoI6gy4BrR8oL9OEPT9EvQTdtAZNDWglOypNzoIDh0klmzgjezA5eZm120CW/ahfWbDFLLmoGkPpwpEblEdfuNLlyCAtX1WgZ777QCoTkm2fWCY5L6DgWNeMjFuAsHfMgSkQBogSmn7xIr3gamcjBxTkSeIUs4wGduunAIDRoxQ8x0U3iaz@Q04TecSg8Uzo2UxVNb3TDKoMZkUwWNwypb0aKJoD8yj9EiW4dU2ur4FX2fQ7aJ14HAup3BZIcWupUePgLUplJzd63dt0w4a3Jc9fixkCrYAYzwUm9ooM6UgziMxmNaAoUAY0f3w0FrgnpCwq6SgII9uJhK2PM/1eLpBx3OvGDlgMCmO1B23h9ydvSKBCyVoGNbaDg7vRV9KXakxU4SI@lSSl5NJ7RvXdpTr5MLCQrKUrEKPubCwCaYNNG2iKQ2mTTKpZMJwGpooRoZM6FujGOhWT97UQsjDVB2bwxB7@3d2XzFqpdJyPWPUdPHN4zcFeIYeA0Kr@AE4yVSlgsZUSq5eQUG1Znuy9DvY652Ynt0XSPiOcWlwu8DCMqEBKs71cGBQRuHlbpz0Kh5IFzAYMDuKlzyr5c7qZ9dnrfTZTTKDsVNlo9KEQkF6Sk8799wBiCGp2kpJ1eupVG0ZhI9mJZlLLilKUYVhHIxEUp8VU2mDY1tJWtAbKmdnSUCqwE/N7HgEb5jJp1IRqiAfKPCArK0ktesipN9M1VPpJMRNJTMwdKskk4AZE5HgU6GxLU0g6PD4C46YnXRaouYNo1L83epOwQ0HvZPRjwbv3iHv4jCaEYV1BwaX8voiQPbACcNq6Dk1aA29mm2GfHQijc/dNh8V7eBr79m@ZA2ptj4/3N87rlAyHcO/AJlCPcewWZCVASteSwNu0B20LGlWGGAbYDLHOcG5A0z83DSZ6jIKppo8E7HuwmRzoAGvIcHTZWq3N1kEvwP53ZkoAwEhd4p5l/xihlniwWfmKUpyHzj2zsmziSmy3gXIE8z0uyh8qx4vAFizS9yxRZ9ojFFiBzRGc0DABNoC@bIVzQU4rqMiLwyHc248IT4hAiHIDaUtlCTsiTAIuG0PYUicwPkUIfqjxIrS/47rwODU0l4RN5QZMHKcrbK0mfL/ERekNNMft06Q9MHY7xom8PtJcGcyOwOAwIGy2dk@qfItwNODAxrH31dGEKVMw0H8tWwapw5sv4PohbEE9gJeG7CKg1Sc3CGsHTATpNxzwLQ1tAM@aoUWfoJRnhq@ksJx0hYfZyCVoYyMmQpn7kiAdU0Y4VsgK6Mvny5he86l7bkOIlnbA9DAispYB1PAZ6EXyGhr6yC/Ox@/s4ADxm456zHcxqFOI9f0oXU5btc9d9kSBEDS1DRO2AcOznDCKCcw@tCi7HeEoK1zF4b6kzRoWdGc6epyNN40MGSWwmvfQC/AZhd6HGBOmU8OvrcHYoheyOUg/6EtR09UyBiU6TKio8nGAcQqQBfpBmvye1a/M/ImyMl3xbxJQJOH1DD5TJYBIiTkSrTwdxQ13si5C7Tz0KsVmmaVfY/GBDh5Fx9XT5R@QlrhzQZKmJhyRtcQFRNAb1X4uH6RcZ1lJ/hWNFWgtntuYGS/1IBF40tCCVm1mexnkwvJrKriWyYvlq@ybMu6zCKXGkMe7lnmTNhDyzKz6IudGwsNM9ETes5BzRk8Dr2gmPwb4iCKOV3@83QaGTvlLkqbZxo6@dPOwJIss@My@QyGGPGSydBBdGCsrALmQQDEcUkUTawISYE7gGFdy@raPTs4oDn7roNjF42Yt4ZcS/juAL8ZAziyLRDI@YTDuJPBefVxH@Wc8/DHwMkJKgzxNY5Sz2pll8bQnruuB@NKn@k0p5CPUN8THlnX77e0YAgAeKw96t/9sJ9/cbi71zjaOn1ayQ58L9u1m8AjWlajB4PZLjSHOQ/mDWcI94B2bMft2VCiEOS7i@6x6wZceMCFg4c9CYwYwni223h2sH28dfy1yBz16HZv0DUwj6XFqQARjBMKcycY0226IFs4g7mQQLg43D58FkL5zstnB1uN3b2jw9MYmG8GXdvQh9n@xfm8An0HgzBdy3HUH3Zbkys6NEydmEUQzAbHXGUGY1OmqvBW0Y0niqMyDT1QRMbuUVVxFtjAeW6P5fXc@nqraRSL1mrLXFlZaxvtVmslrxcL7WIhX8jBa2113WLvKbiqWkOauQETnxXBCSRMAzJPH11bCSUcGIqaILGMZuYr8r0jc2ahYK2trBvr5vr6upFfay0b@eKaZa2utVdyOWtVz7WbRb24fGfmYtlA0Wps69EMELQ6nCwgT2B@CnwmmgPPPMh6V6yVz@dXzUJ7fTnfKuRWWs31XKHYauprRnPdyrVXlvW83jLzeimMizOqwCU6UGEoVTogmoZeqg6eKSnsTONVTKuM4TK0YDiLy8hi@uEyMg4chMcKegzEIjJOzQr3ArqHS8g4RSPcV9G9hwvIY0mWrJGjCFikgLiOrHnN0HEdHaMV5Im1VWCVgn/O8p8fSUC@1nM3CPwK16Bj5bvWdXK/DNrtCec8OV@o2JV1x87L5MxXoCfXfkVhb3nNDBzBWyF4fOV6JrxbXjMDR/AKHB6ueM8GN@UzK2gEbJWA4Qr5TFhTHjMCRpDWCFJ8VX3sVyS/eUvqIq2Z3nMjRbDXCTZfLW98w1crGmKxHKmZN5BTkMSeuSA/P7Nx3r490WKkaAR@JsnhNMLkRNLYJz9eJmHq5ez1HTkOiDMD27lwaeAcmRo5TS8glAhE76J7O2Ybhhr0mgh6K1O3fXj/1Wu26TUjAHa60zNz5EHTnqLrh67WyB7TBydAZ@Vgcip3Ivmm1R7AKCjbtB003xNMXS9SyHazac8LCpjAzQfhd0awEjsewEg0r61oejjsxaUT4Nl8Hvb04JACNg0axE3O/7MJ5AcDL4BY4vtfvt@CSrhdRR1jRGPByNBwrCuij/bcGhNR0UKv2bU77vUJMWS6D6Rp4JKr0Y0Ms0FT7atqx/B6OOQS1Q0Eii@ghDtojeecz8WE39mJlBgheXKdgTl2j5kzQlPYqSURnhgNsruu0SI08KGwbVEkDyubV4M15IPCmMADPc@8hGasXLDxVoGgMwgG/I27A@6rRruPv7uaqAiZKxhN3QIR2Wja1h2V7hkXg5argqRHRcaMrc4IOy49Tdap7a5xwY0NNM4uPi@gZ5@fgzwhvvOCXXVgbEOD0uwVfe6jC98Z@H21CZUVQMMhGzWF3h0peF3@nhfEFvvnIsN8rNldej2g0iPiInIBkY4QjVua1BjS7Ck0d43mCIfqnU@nMkyQBBzgORUznc4tY7cXrf3GtyLNj499JcVfX58dm2@m4iiZNbzK8k1UKp9ApjKLbVX3VCx0XHbP6Kr5Vsw4l6OHU8dj04ygNG@jml3DB9IKRHVYl1B99LqL3LFnMmHY5Y1NdxD7ODvhFoB5q8mCbYlWbbpd28em3Z3HQacX4MZp4nY2esWmpO1ZiG2RzOR31Mg0my@4ZoBLuXMI7QFcjq@i4jp1jHI0dx7STPcKf3NFi457afH37I7u3cxcPYBjqV0iCduc2aO0zPsoFbcD0Ws2Hi9m5iswuzPdJ9tAOMURH6A9kK59u@v67ITed6Hl3INo/D2bouMYtA1HpfWguHl2NJGpPtPELOucejW65253tXieNeA1t/IHXhv7BPF9KPeLuJeu38@9QvnIdXTxncv2L7LexX11R0sTHi7ax4x39MCzWJhYlJxfQBhJ4E6c2YXbzxUpppbl4@V5FeCZnStjFH5/gZ5lHnbDnqU/InkbxD@MsF4EQ@BxGfwXSW3l7tRaD2NPt8Cu3VeIWOVedC3oyOh9q0pZPqd/Ygw9l3s4s2p3B9bAmsmrDpvfWLi//Y5RyMMzlRPFWBSznTgjhHOdUah3Yvz4oFxjH462OxmM0bWhkd8r6czkd32Q0fs45D4CwxEabkc8dwb9icqdGMU5x3djrtMPW7bbmsgk@nwqRyreL09NCPK@Rb87B1d8MIhrW5WVXC4n5JvY/PWE5a5B13IU9xubvycSJpdxyuOwOBvixYyz0xhPpULV2xe@ipOaD@NO@XkzAhR4fT3r2I4VjPA9r0pmcdum63Y/pQqB6bZslN9AKsWFn/uq8pZsJHaDsfHch48zJ832vFkP3iGJ0SlgDwfed1FDfOr1QdWs4pI1tNLzKevd80Cxidz7UoFuniaX@NaJ7nzBU8yo6FpRW7uzRXJx1m1aXYN/hqsrd8Fb15bvhBeJLEJOprUtXA/jK2DjFdXEFN/qjwBZdgsGOR2rZ5H1jtGB0fpm4IefuYGGLv5meGu03jgvXt8GRuHge2K1LSZKBa4Dw7LA8M4tHNd0cVVcuM5jzuGs@kzkHvSMc4ufq7qLe46nOnDrMB8Njo2zJz1KfNeZCdH41o@7SQEa04U18sPvTIDPRybU56B3/1TdVLs3aaPSfQ1dy85cTLhHVnQ6bsfpWB2@EyiyzWseQJEBPxF3VyEg/@cdkxF/iu9SimO263a7D8Es8kfOLV23PTNPe3hOqwVRPwnuyGiCh/jcOwUIfT0hiDr9ee2mYw2gy/LdwO1bKtnmBe3iZBF/z@Oi4eLOLzoLdecMAWAk/P6i8O8dm54bbtDv06fR7w58elFUlY7XzarKfUrmIVRhB3zbEadb69xtmh37viw1LSNw7ItsOCPErXeObPsxLNhM3UVnrWsD8ryRhtRQifuf4OdgXpWKySXebUWG2XVcYjsDzxshJgLXZX7XvRrzh8n9E9E0Ll99QMO8HIiVwRneJA3gzrpwB9kdSyBiIXEugZEQjgK3auVAYNHnzihNbO@MtY7lZf6aJxdNlZ8yFVu//ZQpUbHtgSYH7djMLbhP0M/EYvTMzsrpDM792@yOT9i3QMTC18ya3jrHM81TFc0rFXogwxGfefjOd7O4fRu@Dai5gXXn6krhzuUVCqd3VcO14dOAD9ThYO60Wdfu@/zN1HZ@psBwewn5dqjR7GGzqJ@W1eZrIWi6T9LruR4eIgKRQjU9yzdxKh05MpefOPdx3HPgzGqXjQOHYWcW4faq9czqj3o89asX1rmB2yuf2bjTsjuDKgDq9OL1fUC/OzB8@7sDN7BmwptewL4P3HPj3DafTmA@BBZiVOzB458Jsken28i/6tg@nd8IDXfMOSGRcbJFOmuAvD9rtDY1XR8djL57WiUmKIm930w9YOEe8ciACwbob8xMa9ZMvNunceOITHdNwtsBzcyK70yqmr0J4K7krwa9/sAXn9mp0z6d@BR174Lc/Ssb2KL6Frgx6xjdYPY0dmxmFmQu0UmOjfOk8O/ZXfecfa@YYyCiQaeNQvkMgtuG7vrICKBFODMImNJ@4EIpTnqoHi/YW6AJa5mptmMHd0/wBIEBY6Twi4XhnQ2eQsw@w7f25FMhqKezMfLsTgkG@vaR2cVD8Z86EuBsF6jwhA6tozE6Nx@ne5GMtSMAhr2LY13Fx2t3LvqUsEt1nUGg4i7/u/qU1Tv7lBIbFldjpMGU7@49f5mKUwhtf71PDrVgIDjwu6Oxae7GgynCsx0Q1ubz4snQ4Whi1yKVBse0UfOeOFt9PD1FLH/XnTXiORpB7/PgIRN0IIPermXiyuO9ab9wn4PoBl1ZH5hu79jCLQNTvGR2RIz2zDWNLuCndW8yJwR2Rl8xHlwbfasJ9dsdm2bLYrMA7xqBMUd2oolDGgFGpntpxe42Le8bmhGMmecNaicz9NQa0jBkPsHwVqgGpskFbpyWm2gj02s7ft91Hf4mJpyDj/78bmYD3QO9Hr7iruH@5Yneb@YgbbK0h5d8u4nV4gf35hXXs5pul7@xCHPYgWPzzQWGZ1t@9pntDIbkxlSQ3WYPc/g23py2htMcfgca25UNY@xody9uVuNbhf2pkRSIxJeGT0v@s8c0EzuJH76rqGN4potrZ8LwiStnsSNh9/DxaKs035rQhEoZAkMzzEGoV@CerHZ7zR695o5JYjV9bDXxyF2Tzo8GxnCWEDl5dEw4Th3eClkaNvxVphzBqCd1f0c2PWSbxLjdpxcx9KuZZBIm98K2zHdG6h5eGrUimkvOGjSindmQJjfBgZjTtdSgg3sss0Ewj2G8sC8GrQesdYULKIOehWvWkys3c4nK9TtEEe7sVfqI4XqW2LqNuwSh6Ydm5Lrq1lySRfDwf7j9nSx0zI3VFTzBPxiq58DO7t8XAJkfeI74PITsjlw/aNvDwz6qcXK9efwFi1WAKPDhzQFNS/MKAfXpDLp8vuM8tqOr16LxHUiDbRdMXWLhgaVazqVKKo6G4XKlZ4R6ZObW4fTmUP2e3aFXfrQeCB5q36dvtu8fHTw7PNX6vn7HzCFu@BvYXVzdo6yEblBAMs2foj6hvWoPXKxQ4YOrcROf@fsj@h2jaQVG1pg71EFfK5gt9z09ff4sPT63zJSdjuf2rFTce@fkJAM5Z985mekdj70PBN52h3OjH@zpemoGBb50aEVwHtebkdI8SKcWDFiBnp7yI7T3ykym27dap6O@9SV0iMh5/Qcmvzq3kC@MS/scGxJbn4soamtsXVtdCYN8CYNxPBJ196jkCxvkWJDPTfqm7gl9TLLA8i@85D8tnLCc2IrwaZH0XDiLJqg1sPFo4XmHTL@0zOm6Pg/dJ0YbqpcV5tbZRABx@Iz0ZEUaVfyMOBYJbrYnVC/4Wqj0TZwhJZEgPM0EjoZpDnD2EqhBYxRQUYx0OpWSRKyn7hXroUYpjOTTUegLu19mudCIyOmA1EfhURmEwhYNtlFh@XyOpVJlrlcFWATwvYFVZm07BL3l@/a5A1kIc0AqsVBdDte25TMYWgYh3FqNLV4PS7mSfsMqTC7JrF7nOcaHEtkb9kmf1TGPXls06pXFpKomF5NnTonlklFwq@tbs4MbE2Ehs/gRGY7wy3XduaSoLsJmmasDAlEHVW11DKcFDUEwDii/x5XacI1Jp7hF/i//sCU0kJGmvZ7tG11ACCoRBB7Wca82ebohuvp9AzWYIYyrDi5/YOrqzhbzr3Apgyseg@p6uX9aFOqMhMZCsBzxCe4oF5xycJUdj2YHnDB4bqJjtiLhKFZYKBjzD3oOCNmtoONr7MSmU9cDb3yOSuhxdAIPl9JaGXbAWhbuRqbD9LRy3HXdCzpghzn5yz/kSpzoSL046hwmT8rbYiniyXmdNCeZpjuAXIdA3lmeK4IoiGTDDAa4T4N0B5J7Cg@ak3YpoHY11K1EyXAFSztbJ0zdY0nUSoi6UMp2W1ncOv78y1quXvnAelnrv3w/m7oWiJM/U9dXfTnDwiDlGySsuHcBvMe@SSYvDmWeYKRvwBY89YrXB2pU5ESGKgdCGnPdfthscJhI6uAiahRqVhQ0Uz2HSpZ6pFqPCNa6IiVLdLDVQbmFVDv60MDAmiLQvNVVFpUB3zqgngSsAAmioioDTFwZH53AR4VBGGVxyN4zki2A2@mFHNg4Iruoo6pX2Q7PqizHzxBld63mgPbRX@a1fKFCxVlsVDaqZAI51EVdcbXXZ8N8Tj0bru3VYeQrkHp2Nvwsl/8KsO56EOtxFlve3ovd60Wtmnv/3jdGTJZvkmV@5gnYxOL10cHR3snp1unLE6iFm5C17fOTjyGvQSqiw8wdt0ta@AAvOAT9BP4T2cZsEPW8plJS/NgpBRW4llV5kRtjrGki9j3RZ8X3rZj/7QCCp7VtJkU9A1CBQcSGWMPCD/qoS5CJuEIfGlGZjf0HNqAIMXiybAYvJVTJrALIUgFZD0QVm1/YTe72EIzdC@VutG3ODIIYi9KrRf68iDNRcPNLKXff8P2/f7k5lLvLTWHuKDcEjVzDOPtbB89eHu9NRgs7eeK6lfWCOG/NmTO2ND6MDRXAkZoTERG3XlRkJlMEbhWdGVdDawVXFhRLMEezxyMThVL@ZWlMmICZCmpCrgspRFEoByjfoCAyfRwcxpixLIZ9dAzcNS9ixAT25Qh0mHFNFpATpNFXwycsBkIV6Aqb3hExccGvk35c/MmELQ6Lhn30wOdtbk5XFfU6PoP/WK8UmvJ1NmSiO9PrTGV5@HUt5xwKHIZNlXkfxRY5IuRFnnc5yi9qYoU8tb4xaLWTjjmJY9TQS3eNvh8Kgwn2wg2sEns7cElVS8hMIvmClAAbXHEyVS1XB0wqYGCgBRJ32G8RvIP9kwpKZ1w0I/4ep7mBgx0VBOI6jIUyhcBDXd/8lDtXJspR7gq9lWFXSTOGvtBTF0kJPru0fRtGXVQJbZRxusApsTSi4KgHm5T0wODBB5mkBd03SCgBdrUgnGh09pYfwFUdJieAJrVIZMwwWcKwfuW2HkPoSq9wGPiGR16kcATZj8FMbiyoKmDu3HZCpdcl1IJNk2UlFngD3FpbTd6KEmahRCa1E/S6sYAzNLqeWdmPv/E7XIvrWQDmHwnzMLcNtl8TtjaYfz300XWw/bPIlgfbj7ntdRar7LbqynE@Iy0kc08rA3E@kW8VDBlDqP6bChRVOVb3lwdHzDdRqzRWaA8G8@O6QjYTjlOY3QPKuKSKxuA8hXE9juEoNRwZA3EBkaCMg2INpWd5dQW1GJayWcw4LoJqtMfZGvJ9R6TU8O0AlfmCJJZdLayu6FnIpHoZAiQ9S@d45JIDTKVKwBilS7tfedM02cbGBpN90@haldUyJ5DsovF6WX4TZXQRwkp8tFBjEAeijGOAX1VEUxaNtJ7CqNibJfUkMraWy@kNREKFDBAkhc5OqJkFZE5XoAqI2bGGAYlNo3AUBFzbcWNavENAKgDisFHl7HSbHB@jxJn7WCvV4tUgv8JgNHVVkmdRbO01OwvOnLpQPcyA@n46g34dMP@TGfqIOWWh5qnbinCVaTW2WBr25MRxcQFkH3LLlHw2v5zVV1MxCpUFKMgvtvf3ABJaOHAM07K/cfv@1s7ewXcOj05uKUSjkMnpYEmWrG6kz1QtU6tHhmSU70mkbu9nT55v74eojOdqvASBIcZ7yqezOSu16ZzOSf0VP7F6O23yuJWQnnsoYJq/VPfpbMZt6GPfbCzgDj8wdytVJXV9U6tvVM@cxK3k389Scp3QlpC4wHTmk4rr5HQ2MYvRhRaneKGFr4XqGHTUxYCHdAP3YqzZQTjEPHjwEApwAEnLhqHmMU/IwCGfARqrIMrzGzV8Yn18lohUD0c5ioU8De/ewKY11pgpVEV2DL/TtZsSdOAtVJ/KFT2FmowiFVGa3@/agZKSaAqkgmIQMDFF3MAxLA012jmhkKJrgpVhd2mfDOGlJGgEAC95NPA77Mjtx@a2dq3QdAzSCNsd8GV1i31n0INwbfocW8hiLZBPVIgMiEpGWeWjamhZQvnkMI0KPiG9GqqgFAXXeq2CMkxpHWvYss@BgSupDLT0z3QQqyL1GFhoUkjpJIHHcQx/jgcV4yj9JB2kwzFwo2ZottOyhgoq1SrVQT5F9@TVq8tkSr5FA6QIdSdUnTilETVsiEYgWsRYm@hUY1uPrt2YUlm7vo6KyVDTB1QLpHgSeM/ACP2T0u4ZfaYMSFWvzzRGVuVMcTJ@4KWYWuXafhyWTtOoGj7kAVIzBm2TiQiHKTgPqWQrUDvo6jst/Lyz@6yma1odzJRIii3ijNoOdOU4F5WSYJQEUUoEtoJ1y0qYI069Gqc8iIP@EukOZKivdoY3aZil2XkXcUGlZtXHMZ1r4xbIsbq@XhK1Mclq1hmQxW0ur2UB7AwWEkqpgF@huAGwhjcw4FUduG4HbOHJF5bjWIAgoJmeAX2wMQAi81KZ8MqdzFhjP6WQ4Fl8KjRBQEYnNfnvJa@7uLljMVumyZnyDfSpb86wU22LbnWU/e@zWrZ8rSx2K6MsCDqpqrLYqejp5aV0etFZUhYd7OofP8Y5nZtFkCQaGgyRhhBIXeymykDPIHlUFp3yorGhLLYq@SWKAVYYpF1DhA9@VrteNG6yi4@hp86Ai8cbr7LokzLYnKbpN5A/bCGL2QzQzDXqzqT7djD5RTudxjxoiw3MwIfs2UmaePbZSZamj8pCGs2e90Rzm@KqUU3cum2II1A4i4oGxp5Hxi4O4DTCwGM9/suz/ObIHjzhL3BNgdG2asuPi//ypM/DGYvgd0nS08dV73JtvIDAoQJIRGvGSKWAmfz85wl9lcnK4ubqcvcynSzkyvDSy2uswD5bPMuvJFjiiWEEMGTPLl2f7RbPL5nVzq@@VdWa3dbe1o8ujo6@Go5SZ0oysXP4WtZXIOgaW6ffQ581lp/zsE97EomlrJTILumP17LZN2/egMiLT62qVcMgWj1VU5P1mrImHHrVtbWlzGpxKXP8JNmAvEBxU0o@nzphtp1lZ3bfb7Xg53bo9islwR@2uYnpgQH@mXDrDdtkHG5Z5@eDPWPE3e3EAD/7gYj7/HuvXr1Cwyt62LtjET/BIQpwiVLDKCQok/lc/i//dOEmc33U2PjLH/Sy1gJ@DvHzo5vnaD7RC58tLHy2vb2ykgHEcfPR946@3traWtnNFI5qhc0VNbew8Rd/vrCQz2/kswt139frydrFV3I@tyJrf/n7ycbR0Xd9H@sOn2WmgxHfRfjprFBgF@wdPBdthv9kfteKmQ00N9vvsIMEYblCzCaZLCwnT14nsX7eJXRdT4zor0FFW2B6dXPtv/7m4dtEkKjms688@AaJt4nVYoIbwQC25dB2magmNjDY6k1ilK1UKmBc@6//DuJXvwNw0Ge0Aa9qIYS1OkpU1QpFeZ@oroJBz@ch3f/7@99nT2rwyCtreXmzDs8SPhtSojqErFWrB/ssX80vCeLRi4/1x2Rygg6IHWcJvbhy@ISstvXkMF/Ib6DZsfAuIRij0jhY1/NnTFSpLioWkaDjmzuwDpixpt0EC4OOKYGFdMZeJYhqgGyIcrhZOBAxcYdX0@FenRnG0lp6Jf/EKb@KPROWX/5zjFe2rS48ebObzW5UoffHp1R6ctYQTS/L1oqy6z7BCcEyeyZcy/gauqrqQnD4nZGjio9AX6JYyTQ4isKWF/qwsY3FnRICkyxqZL9AuD18/ur//Kuf/NVv0t9P6PefpES4IUutXdar4QP0I1c9@fpMWJ3n7Dl/HAf@4Rda0QUdwOSI@cpE9FSr@KJ/YSMTfafchE81slCIcZS54VjIxShdKfEhm2XYAthlWJgnC6WFYmm1lM82wuJRMXjOyfA8Vrpx@Xh5NuFZgD/6hyey4nuBXIQzBbn9LLDqQ56ZvYKUqCVq9Tpv0tV4/dz9HGtIc5qwNeL9zKWUUIF1pdPHQKNMkDY8Z@l7npfw07SGsGW1MdSElPilP1WJJa7hqafVm5ua9jpdLot/EPnKkQ0fboKsJVfc5Kr7pH6jqhuvq@l0jXJaq4osb6isXuUFoLfWeL0B4NMbtY2Ku0M/jUhErb@u1jYmI1P8evXJkzSi9gkAqC7WGQw2oDZuNm6qN7WNm5uNDfjfoPeN@ILrzcatf/qMnzlhxv51rP@zWrZ6lhVtsloHu5atoouWPQNDFb4QDjoFKXGNpMNqdVJzWFFr@mqhrjJqIEvAvLIlfSm/nC0MP1vdywMP8DF4XpazS2h4jz0oyEDrUgJHE@t8ULFODm8@fvu/4@/s47f/BqyQN7xPknybb/Hv2Tv8exvg36mJf8dv8Y@dvsO/4wD/njfx78jHv9O3@LfVxL/THv5JiQpjINctbua6ucucfqFfgMFmORCrO7mO3oLOh@UslhvlRizXc/UWmCz4y4HJzrVZ7pzlnJyj6@AJhoDlAjS14XMOf22A4sGfncsh8Nwlg1S62KWRxnD6vm@w1JlUY8k3Fghjmq7ltFW7US@s9t/WkvVyInt2luUSKsuvlElD/M0NY43G3ovdRiOLDeLsuXs4/j887MWtd/73Dt3nh27Phf/Dw8PnZ8DSquknafUJPJVqekN8NhPV8uZZSUViDsk6kd3YPKsuq2heTQOl5tEt/YnPGCJ8qwtnEozgX726KlO/W766LF@VyRBZuaEhAohg3ACxyqK/BheId/YqS33sFTyXBJdsaLwCz9DEDdlXV2coZ8KoIvoHdMStv4R/@/9b/89fMqVWT0EjuL7ZUOhJ4V8qdX1zfSPe1ZSiCIuyAX/oAHaMcn1TRSMFugZTTUnVUzc33A3eSmqDA6xiGhtVijwOCMwjEaVJ6fKX8sv9Ytr8OUuC4ATjbUUsFp6dDXO5VLkJLtGKgfGe1p1SZdqRs9jEtUIYY@opClFYKZf1JW7Or@TL5RVhWSuWy0VhXlSU9dtPNbepr4J0sLKSSpXLOREWRpPl0AggLN8wy9jIy4kUZpa3fCWHc5Z0N0xSLsmPHyviNqHNfj/1@LG@nnv/PnJqNFq212ig@/L793JDxs07lfUC2HPF9@@B6SRTrqe8cPmysaLq7LN8lVJYdz0o1Rp4Mz2bH6fZMXwjCDzlnd3PyLgj2JdTpM89l3O9s@TPfvyDH5wlK7idg1xXdASAqbDCxsbqSrW6ugLm1SIUXF7k@4OU8/S6nrpZzMq8uExeTCaEl15cS5HrTRL9WWKDbVahofr4sOubBNUfWymklObISl2DS@imr69zR7ayqhTT6@KvspBi1SUm/qDnWk6vLK0tPYHhzPD2g0y1fG1Uktls8qZybZRwbuumbIp7Q/CsnvH48fI6ILOYK59Jjcbu1ulWA68cxZV76BAZOhKHlnBVtu8lazQRWViv17Bg9bNkslR@QtWuFwsskSyLcGoSuD0rrlP5E74v2W08tDskqFO/pUSf6WvL0NNCRyv1aRPVWo61cB3aY267vQCOUHesiVsGfKvbDe9auXK9buvKblkLUuLo2dbO3mkmD1JLIr@/tZPJn7zcTuhoLYzt6M0Sy@hwvLe1e/gSYhw929s62fv84Mu9l0fg7kvfeO8MyzKsgWU1rgaDq7fsG9tu2IC97sC2bdf0IBcNy7L6ECx6ypZl2r7xzTeG16eHcW798ae/8vGn/8PH3/vxx9/7lY@/95OfffuTX4HfH8Lvx/z743@7XsD3z779Z3/w8Xd/Dxz/E/z@I/z@9Gff/tb3@Y/sfwa//xxz@zPxi4XjPwlg/drPvv3N3//Zt7/@2/D7l@L327d/v/Gns38/@eH8H8b7zT@4O8yP/x38/ojDCsP@@He5G35vhf9dHu7Xf/vjv/j3/P8vxB8af@/jv/gzfAnLP/3tv/jPH3/wH/L54l/864@/8uOPP/zNjz/8wccf/ujjD/9x/uNv/Ws9F3/9wcef/PF/@5M/@m9/8j/R/x/S@48e8v/xt//pX/8ff/1//fWfiN@fwu/fg@lP//o/AOn@7R//FP9/84//9j/@FP//t3/1t3/8P//tr/2vZPgdbvh//uW/5e@/@cGv/M0P//nf/ODbOe9fufP97QPcv/0HcHl4Ph8C5yHl@lSXb3@h/Px9sDFOBWiALkJheRBqt0cWTWh8NixJn7FElSaYcM6pmC@ml0AeXVpfj008QRAmQTv9yT/5@Fu/CuT/LwAY2P5HsME/t4DXj8jCvvpqwpOlaZJETX/1FXqKceVX8VA/Aof3WZDOc0/eQ4ivyJs/LAoG6f4vFAzCMREsDDeZAQqDO0O5@8@@/ee/Tx5RXHT@1QmQudA5HnoRg78Pi/ojbPfj0sRD/whZx8effv/j7//jjz/9nY8//TXsK9SV9cxWBrr6u@eGIWDhAeEw4OpDwkFAHceVbIEtSHkwLGzgfKakp9@8gdwvgAmGYEtSYRlskl4ls45miJgGGwEZDtP4hn9pZZ2hBVyG5Apflgav7TSrVCppaVgBPwoKVowzZNUiOA1x/qECcDESj5NpFGFww4bbBAViVtLHrLFUGfKIaXSoEgQkGwmdjmU9L6eLlV1IsDLcZQgLgaelN/B9U6kWK8MqgvtAWQAY6W1IEkJVMHfD6gewVwgmhJeGux8gK8VKOl0tgksFC5mm1DINSlMvUOGo7GlG5UZ3xnCH5uYTaDKyXpT5/AigkonQ@E6PQ2NACA7@Z@klURz6D430W8L4UE9Dwg934/6b6EzxRQCAq6q4sQ9@qoq5eQLeQw4qTcnCJ80hAObSJFWFIMGBBJi0lKb6TZMF0oc8fNqzgawCwWFxFhcXwbRRlZflxiGMKWHw5l2U/MDwcOGRBMsSk1fXZXTGXVJ8/@fiEQ0@l3aX4K3D/94C7XmmspSXpMUkzmwkedbS7LM0/z15ssQ@g7LTd@wmMTW97K64CV7MjXRazkOSVRdsS1TENAHCmQf6T0uvExJLUN1DY8nwN3y0CrnHmhI5vK5I6bEd5yNFDE3LaJmM@Gr0JQdNGDTyFV9tkSRIPgxi@uoKnXyh2@dSLEX1Y1ooiDHpuX@@7Q5hBJKR5Yy@igtWKTGRc1rKY1uV9ko5eH/tlkqVD/rKmgRfsg/wIjxxJRtQTcfyLG1jA6FXr1WabkIjSLCrUrUq1uqZLlVP9k4h@Okh0/M5jcHo5XplLb9SWCnkl1dXC2t5fWV1fWW1UFwGvrqaK@Tz@vrKynpxfe0mwtUTYE2Z0lKzsFH9R7ee/@4fzXpmu@IjVb9iQ40m2G@karfC94wu4rq9fJaTyzT1RahcrOUy@JdfXoY35DOjF9bqCwvdaxWLfUYbFa9xZwRkVbpWsdt7BA@THknsETjBA2ngyiUTe00ODstiXwHeZ8v3Fsh6AcgY6uEM6JiDk/7/55f3JNj19XXsJyUWvve9gFWrMKJTD/alBHCzDgt3Jah2S@todKVva@BZ5HvO2O7BlwcnB4cvtN2DExhifc3yyzlNStzc3LSjVTOyWuzw8FDCbgSGzss6xr8x2WAwIN8m2G@GhtSPP@UJW1/K59X8srqsq/oy/t9jyOP/w8Pn4T@Pb4i1nJf4ieAuHqIKpyXXkWFKG1zHTRXvo3SNViW6tpgpqetWpeWadDiq3K7U6poPtF1uaU23NdL8YASj6pbt97vGqJJsdl3zIhl62niRFZ4HrGSNrNZoAJ4DF4baNDjfzK8VSgtZL6vhxnGlzVKb@dU1cDlzQidwKaDL60mn9VJLC3P0HBoQxMuX8quFmw2h2q4K5cF8VTEX1yJzJcd1rBvcLFwy2oCGa5NvsinJ@UJRLtfKY/vaqlyu3zzpWS3bYGc5PJt2PTPi6qp8E4aDpHGkjpMoTOnhXTO4C72UO8ul5kTOQWTIMuVU2hB6daq0baIGbLGOV3DW6huhxp2q9OHDhyHtVCodOIHYspRfKaI7k3Bq4DGIWI91biysjo05NJ6idqQXUHfAzB32DE8eBC47dfkO923LnBNip2PQjaQ7nuv7f48w24Zzwb12ba6mJfJ6aqCedr9nB505IV72e3iK1fL@wSDs9ZqQQaQpHmAbXl7XdWcFWGMvj@aU8nmkVQ13N5FaNQh@fPD509PY93Rva@eptMq2D1/sTn0KIlCBPdvbP42sa9w3jFqIQHy99@zZtFV8QE4o0xzWAius4e7m0AI9f8IIDDnTkGv1cgIQE9yAPF0st5zBpv74sb5x9AxPEKyyFRDBl9dypdJilkFTKN98CWWrbF@U@rhh2rf6S351b3jk@esrUF42YC@hBq7KngWiZRGIAtqpLEPr3N/aySYrSWgbwaL0HDdVr@v8hKDtS3RQF@@8xPttAwn1uLTcK4cOPza7A4sN@myuI3zQCY2efd4JWHDlhgGkpmEw@H3qA/Gt@BPc7RDwNMjtlk93RnDcxWO3WU7SiAnn14uF4vpyvpgprhdXCvpqoZDR8xl9rbi2DqJITi/qq8XCup4prqwvr4C8BL6F9TUpASKE3c5mQSTVZRm@JQDrmHhN0wbed@VqnaqU4HPL7J1ipKDWI/uAyRbEkfHCUD@gcyNLdkXOr@ChrmWdAUSDmSyxv7@T29@X5W204NLXTk6WW2gpFHO5tW1ZtshnB2S6vCy7PE4Rj7PLAbfkcts7sjzgAFDpmyx30LK3iuNlWbbRsrO1v4/ptNGSx/gQ7IL7cEs3tKxBMActy8s04JbltxE4CLfFE1qhnO6hBdNEn33uswN@svx5mJ9cDiAc83AcwtOwrFtbsnzALVtb6LNDBS/wrH6Bli16ZNkDCxChLJ@D4Rz7AllughFJUZZNMJkjA9zwSixUBOZA@5NHHEGIIlkeUmjDvJBhWCjcMZmnT58anaBlnfNn5PEvNKwD8LGHg7395uefN8/Pm95oa@/zY/TZ2XlqtEcDr3neFNGaDXhciAM@F73R9AN5PGg0jO5Mny/Ax5nyaYwaFuatYbyFPInnHBPpNXbAZwd8ZszPDzk0eHoQtInPdg@@20aTfMKHfOg7bDblMhJqMOpbOJ@ObebCAV6Q6Rmm55bRPqwssKSSzIxqq7l6mdxZT2Gpa2BZ6N9W6NplHFKB8H09qg0ruXplWFnLi8Nninw2zBdsObPQ29TXQTIxNvX8SnpYQq3@bjvJkqq@qeiPl94pL0AIWV4pyWebm6pc0@ubeb1YWl17vTSQ5VQJ35vLa6V3MO5KwuAKX6naWn0TxJ1xlLW1tJHNl9Zwl16qfAMYCaA7ag4Cq9FQlCvLuEilMMfYyYMIRsVlIyqqXW4rw8ywwjPGRqnysKKXuUoalrsFq4U60QZ4wymHeA7ghpu5Eq5pKLK@XpQh/WxWSaWQKyEfge@bV@GSa/SJGSaM/NFYSeXXI@vF1ZSGR5kabrtBV0SyN/GQ4w0L0is8fUiaB8JNwjTk90vSKQ44sTsgucpu4r3spMBiKA25Nj/G5yD1tXVJqorx1hG/oq4srJ8/3dFgCCZsqGNN20e51vU0vEY@mPDh@r9Cp1Po3bSnFm79NUO3Ha4TQNsbwvgahePQ45k4j6YJxSja6dPytdrAhZDvnl6cnn6l3sTBnsDYk2cEz06VSTkHaiFAjXR2ixmVKpgMlCIpl4CC1BWho1GtVhqVntXrByMocxjvC643egzowOeFic50UfRrPOcoPBqV3M04/ItBj23zQHQYMozWqGwDfnNlB/W5WmhdZMPEUKq2UF3ddmX7elBCSfSmbFUsz3M9OYEnSDedysDxjbZ1ZHl4ePHgcJG1mYXHBM3Om7M9DLmDIvWNWvWYM5EPxVCrzdSkU8yKqFO@G2Hkmrbf49LdDYxMlNep8luweYtMaWnbqc2VckvZZo0UuOTetN@0WZ6trpTp9hIFIQE7IMwhRoxUpfoFAOZwL0olyIggiQuAiQktQo3YLfIxUn37pnxeqWHo9/jaUGW5rqq193WpWpaqwF3Ko4RR8QdNfs9wrqnnc6vlIbjpayvlDmtWmq@HZa/Sh2EnK3eh2sXUBD9TYOD@ckASwHn3Xvn4q99PbaiFCncrE6z3XRAkGlqjMhxX0HKlll9ZzeRXV3AiY3UZfnomv5zHHbOZfG49k9dBngA5A@LDbw3sK/CDMCBu5HWc7lC6isyYnMkNc5qe0S09o@Te2K03qcyFAmIgISyVCdw9B6gGHJB4gGTJCl8jlc4vdZWWy4wNlegXuF2ZCmlkOqxvZzoI5tgyujx4SmXLS0p3UcEwi6eD/l6tXirtDfvfRS9Ffbu5ml7Lpd@lUmVlgaUqvvWWMIyMkVDQXwBqFlM4zB/0arkFKDS0P/UGajpY1NfypdpgsabqULrc@/MNuSrXoapumAR/8XVhkLfK4BbyQC6hjWWssVsfpequBdWqr@fLIojUFxxZkZUzOTz@oiSTa/lkMpUs47TlArgLjk7sNwndQfKxvimDjCeX5PU8@I8Z@a0c8DH7qi4lbiQc1TIYvSeupZvrm434zsAv2GhkpNXQ@pix8/SixLK0YUdrJNgCmVStSpPLW5Wt8@Otsgi9tSMlSrR3dby/kJ0J/QVMzS586jah9Eb1Nf@e4TY5SFYiPYo1VqdVf8vGART7Eo9zbbIklMvwerV8frley69BXw48OAyaz0PR/WuJ45vvK8tupKsseybJMnEfvgmhWEjxUrAPCWrvbOc6nNIoPcdxM1OMEm/ftXrqwwu7e11cVvnYW2GJDyyd1WhvZCP7IQH94w3VQrgN9os3@QLUi@OGDjDKDoC1Q3daKMgpxhb4tut8tO063L2wUcbZ2Tesf7L@eu118fXzl4cvD/fZk1ypWCpOLb@cPclk9KSe3MBx3PsFF0dtH5zvfJeVWTnRTy6vJG@t2JxVEsPKSrj1RNGrVVXfyLNNIG1Wgu6gra@qufdVTqdV8ljNg8/HX/3tleFGEex5EKdLgOhCOl@t6kv5VKL/8dt/g8dir/e@3HrGkqik5O/@/Pfza3/35/@K9jkkb8roll9eS0BINOqra4nr6/719Q083K@QqCd4nlbWUmDme3D0RDUrnPU1PZXw1YSY1V4rJPz3QmuRks8VwW/nkNvkVUBxYu/YLuT1JxuIZv0WmgHRlr@ekBLF52/eMwYWs9o6P7fzZMpmbyFusfRB3YB/9gEntz@oC28q1cUsTtKvY@hw9nCpWq0u4QIaS1bTeAQ8T@ohqrWbch2Qjg8O8JYc@rP8JfxD@2vusOT7YA@9raVv/CXMHStUoW6Xstnsx1/9rXx@9e/@/DfOUu8b7xtfAd9eX19f1fOJn0M@7jiXGY7qaFIIT1iiIRoNsjnXq2qmLCXwzt024@HDsSGOBlErAdfphDbpEoUTqoIGINEAUVyhYEt4uixDQjkdRU@VJSmSXEno9s7NDMFgS6jLGhqcdC09Qi/o8lgFWJ30aAwKHHqoDMps@N2B1ycRUqF4ej3DHkMUSOERqg9ZoFNxgl@qeplll25H5VnmmoRISGE9y/dRgxiwc@kRRHkGVEyXYrG@gScrMaTtAH/WMAjlkzxaNUi7Dml3eYQGuSpUeh4gw3jueCQHpHLpER4TI6kdenJmb0CAMktJjwABUAZFALbrbIMtp9i1nU6XxwrHbnAXI2qbMMJzWxJGQ2gtPKwYRi5jOJsrFRl4qGiLiRo2rbhjCITD4MtrFRhPYHSyoSRERzMfDApg0RF9hYrGHj8e56pSsVspRiVC@KhvDZWkjbVD3UoAgIWDsc9aJTnDnHQaK/vRJNkBxtOUXaA6lQzjQG08QIfWG0mC/wcTLVLkVFWRRxkLIOqLtwoTUAaREe28Dk3UGKfn11IsyrwJeTcpU6R4Jhphng0/00j/k8mzeCP9PBEqg5Xw8vrYUEjQ7fTBPQa92QCvB0OtBJwZiCN5/OIYZE4HQRg7igVFsbsUum17MKig9cJQhY2yrKcwWjtyoXzQ7sX8CsONhYUUfigWhkZFJwYqDRHpLNC8N2lb8/uuQ1pG6MQ2br8k3W@@xHWq8GwPnCuD9IXxVGi3YixHXAkbUj7pCHO4IjSfx8WFyaYHI@QQNxlmnWukTie/zhSu2A9nJ50IXIoiUYZhKGkgjptdqwdZOrEshpou/FI2ew6SyKBJqi2e20BXnX0b@gzHz4qLyLJX9oWdPUVNlqrbBulWHKVMoPBiR1qmhP4IUhLXtS8sPsJVJs7C@iy/mgHpMQOYHf8AsSXs7PG8aw68MzwU/Nbgs8aNxUws7oIySt3@LusLSgNr9D3X1@ThZWOXhhPDLz3vJTEu9Ud@eNCdTl6CXYtYLrRMftoticfdomOYkjiRX6HT4hrOpvcVkMHC85loBInVuoQQqi5hHwNM0wwPjmIrhtI@og6A2h60LNQEE3glPFFdQR1piglNTzB4h33GlvMSacwjHQNCJQDAwKqvTEIHP4iK5fCDFlSMxicngK9A6@y1wC@BipE4@WH8kLrRTFqRxuTNFgQ47HQorQrjzSK0FGIWbB1cxx0UfQE8VyGHM3KyoMhpAJuWUzIHHcWfjs6pXSJeUmK3IWUYQhCoBigoKmwbPlf3KdS4XF1daaRJaODZmuWjwmEfL1HM9s9tEGHdbGD1@uKuGBsv@hKXGI5NKlc4jndubg7pqsv1xyP@laQ2nm1@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@oitqUV6yYN6L@49lf@OTst6FdzM49ESzvF8pSvKlYQ1T0aYnmQlhl1UqsXiEH2SWja3nQQe1xMVR0ypDMUjYcTfB0sAhcQa0Sq3wzxeuHzpjIjlyKSGFUqUARRxXeLHm7CFHKER5F80W0UUgIIj5nIAAjNzOaJaIN49GGlQpnHGw4J9pVLJNDyuSQR@Ghh3MyWRfRYJAUqUDF6qmj5jsQqGSAp/PeErW8ysw3LlGVL/sGNdXA4ClMc8xziAoEDaEkjXRm1memXotlOsa0pgAgId4C0OK315SkaYanq5Et4lEclSGP4jZBBpxXAIERCy5zbWRKRGQ01AW5Xk5TPwBtV07XJFnH/WP0l@M/ORM6hj/9tmNuMqQ@6ZjLTP39gzjWEbOxBhoTMvTcCjJkHLBskXIWEEuuXKbMEJ7BPRteT5xtdt1mtmfgxgu8xzy6tDgVjgdI/eKTvhsYgbuyUuKDIJvo66UIzmI3R/AxgH3uuDDUiGs7tLl2RieJSihN99yxfSuD1yRzEdyiXQJc/7kUl3uF0fUlSUwV8mEpguYEhKJro4FXbDUaim9126lSpEoUrRrSYTIp4XgWTLH4wIcE0MO@4uId8UHqfpioClREO7XNC@WwLzyTkMgWA2ZlgjwPvh0QVZjvjkeCpKMPReNmoJAC@47bc89BvEP9mxh7CvzBGDZmyOj3KS8ZZuAQtRRTmErNQTEzRkpE/eKTo7Iv8oqRiuLnJwFMICPDvGkcI2a9Gck15ibHo4XpnXx6fk/i@T25O780qp7OMx9qV7jnpyW9rIwhQMBxNpbvz0ZGqLu@lZ2JrETOKEDxCA/OYos2NrUwp1sQdEsE19pAH5nI5pMSHpHxL@fh/@4KDKPvPbT6DLxx8GQE/KaH@@cUuv/AD1cQFQh@kELeczu5iLR3H5gWhMVbJfZRVgB5lRiXgxqeoGH2YRjty9EKigB8D83j9qVbdE97mircc0aevMsMu8jPr6LdRsvqGiOrpYiQmRjcsMTHMDIjfvWwgiOjI6bn8kGdAp1UKq4eGpHOA5XmkIyRuYwpB78VhgexI@qhmW/K4cF8/KH/LdaMU3YVPvsMAn8ymSA98qT2vz/qj7hmzC6/DkfwUd7/8JrEk7b3IwTwIDY/ZMbJpu5in8dKVKQH9AhRWG2yyKQDK@y23F7/dh1@GoruLylUbixSJazlCd3d82rcvqvGY1QR0iRf73kYSd5HdA@muRipcWBjFrbzaV3ILci46cE0lThE7nJnjbnOLZ6AbjTv5szpVRozGGoUkzhdYNO4muSLlIRD4AP44gTSl/BFgOdW0OAEFZYN56jEfTKMfHpGPya1CBeQxgFKDIvhDQ2UjVgoKTRD8OubKE1zbprmrTTNiTSjFjCZZCyQZE4kKWoBq@euKuha7WAOd0YvHCTD5y62DY/jGh5OS1wn7WTJzrDkZbIEDDlpJUt7CjDlZCtZ2iWDnyydkOEiWfoCDOO2lXyfLIXNAgN4YCXDE3QXLBztZrK0o6RupAAv0QjT1ZKlqE4hzCa3EkYAFVhukBpxycxxRTEDz4KOjYTKDEOK8TM4TqIJlwz9cvDPteXzW13AE@cslygwSzN9otOI9Rg8Heg2Qj2qM1pySfTme4f7tGlofB0B@KdhMBePQ@BBDE8kJ5kRzxj60goFfCGDyDdLs3PE9Mk7Kx6QHZE6UChV8mT6hD2N5IGWQv41CFxPTV6FIOKH9TUJglfgw/KJkefl81Z2wuQoR7jGmpqRLUTqm@QdhcK6nrrng9d@vIZo7noyEN7QGQbhtURgYzwdZDhabMPE@m5/kkjIF7cC2vE4NPvGGyVS71Q04gqiZc7xJmdRMmQM8cafuqs4sXiYtQkWhJ61XJ23sqhfIF6MXmNeF5NUeeODLMR4DrRwy7ywkGx3hZHCcXaTob5iXjcUxuVJEueaZJMQWUOVIQMj4KlHg9c9VCTyacPXMOYQJ1UUBBCLGaXC@av7CfK7y@X3UKAOkTCVwCzBenZXelu8vrOXncp5d5zs7QpEzwzbTc0UjqIUxiiH0UFMMr@L1m6J@LiFgwv5PNEI@pS0H6ItGhPcg7fpsQWHhVKCdznpeJEHx4v8fETdlki6l1ootGiYkoDDCx7ldFy0u/PKCz6ritGHJrKN7idXsDdZwfHKQ3hUAG8K5byV44lPXNsat21SUosuyFL1EuOMnJY/o2oeOwK7p6XYaBkWHA4bx7uHL559DZ3u2tpaSvTRo3H@sNXipGrUj3PItGE56g9mDFvyGVTSjovXOO9ON94unDnyLV7CmTUIA3g5TUh@oo2nBC@L8fOptgvxeNgYRgWsi3EzMCa4Eoo6BnbZtsBrAAixAmXJEEBC8RbwnaHRWgrnZIE68J67RoO6r0YDNyM1GqIXw6oJV7hTP08sZAe@R1eNchXSV5JEp7PZ7iF79XTrlJ0@3WP7L3e@YF8fvmSvtl6c4vnmo5fbzw52GPz2XpzssfGMAj54rQYOKAGvu5Zp9ZrAsvO53AojyDtuf8T5jrKT4u4nRo89dU0L16M2fKP3pMMtmmMFVR5rD4ajI5zDtOnmlp4dBPxKOhPAkXDToiNtuO@fQdgmjGl7OObtuS27bUNYCce@fdvyw4NXrGtDDQK/DU9TZriQhFd80FYgut6NbubDq90gPC7SABjDH18laPs8gtXSmEBc9HwyBk/3jp@fsK0Xu2zn8MXuwenB4YsTtn94DNajrw9efA74PDg5PT7YfoleFPD54e7B/sHOFjnwDOQ0hifY6a6@u7KgYXDCinmBS9x0dXBki886QzCQ4NmVQYf7fJYcOMh9bKNrv7NaybKEl//wA4W0JsCiq/eY9RaXMsM1X9pPIL/06fqaxRzboNSgsVShvZVFc4VuDxWJ48JDb8TwGiOrTAfLFTKPr0eiTTkt22LyDu45wblvfv6c2nIIGhJaANgIKtyAUmGklT@ZzGwQyCqkZnZdVJrGU@ObAoUFoz4Jt46UJcKY2PuCQPE4wIGD80F6OXIAugeHvEg28HgAthw58ABshTugKHqAe0FYQYQYBIcDZM9slTt80@vv0/ovW4sctg0axRZFnni9UZUabHwlud3rd@leBT7LQ9clGb5p2xTFp/B4L0G3G95Z2LSA5IEnihumcK8ahJSB2bRxqUFsY3MG1LDBF6gB9/0Y7cBnSiWlsVPc7GM5Nr@w4rxrOHxL03grDtEeK6JukYrYvG1HN0HQAYu@SwSIt7NM5iOKtyukQuuh8SDm9q0UDbHnkW4TCreU3ZeB7VsZ@EXAACB1YqRjUk9FRzwRjNsWpKz4LlAkztt@iIcHcm4NTGsiQnij5Df2u3cpgeTMxDgp3HdIuYMqwss3M3zNsu160MaJrfbwuApyQbPj9gOb16EyWYLxfWAQGjs2SO1NpTqRGt0BOpWi4zqxRJtAxXNSbQJRPiRVoni@SB6xr7CtRxeS0T46zI7RdC@t2NpZBheRriycfgFBmF@miL0NXY4r5E9pzDs@0AWXxUp1d/tM/fAmg9cpcLbArxALNxHyCzF7mBY0D1rnow2IHspdoqWFd3L4gybGFnvqBLfEVh4Cg3Fgx4Zx3ZNGOfLj24dvu@NZlGl3cnz/vsJjqciZOEce@B1lzN0yrBYmmaE4dSb2esR4J2QWeL0SumQIZsSvn@CxE6yFMmDEQT5CV9lO3oUhWEhYuuagDZxF3HYlqjuCn2JV2joRCpL0KPH6yL5Wtivpaio73jnCYuhUQhadCSHjZVjj/SfUX90Ct3s3OODfDwdXvDN3vHv4JGi7d0L7pLyp6fmweLcUg/VwsB/uAMs7t18ILJQ9Mx8w7yRvQ4soPSLOzGIi2h17d4pvbtUdtT0Ag30vzqBEQGOpDRxaog41myo8QioOZiwQnZzu7h0fM5mPTyAu8D0cMrQEG0TYC/yqEL571naI2WmR0BQNliPhKXSZ2LoWnfe4ozHPRN4cViFkkIzAR8QsJi/mJK4nehYSIWg3PTHEEHOTubsOeZBfE4BvUJUtMK/EWAyLCijNLGaCdz62H9/ULfCW4bJxfE8@7ZjmfTdeseWN4oDim3@MczwpMrv@XnH5uBSmwwUs6@2ACtwCSRpvmdXYCSTch4CaNlmDd1RLWKW4aZ4L2IkQd7jDKzcpYf/9CYoIiQvhXBaOsXUhHIuscfl4MRRzaOchdgMGbukUnnyHMniELJ5cNuIVmhp3espkFwRCJl7@9CROFRC9flOO7otVxv1kJRLI421tkXJTC3NZx9lZAbs8P9BnuLd5dZo9TCcF3PbOpNRfTlK8l5hIKcT5zMKEngB5tVBYvg/2dCnC6OrfFzbvQ6b5Z9Drw/h@DNIf@TS9D5R78CIT@o8J4A7U8a3yYYOZigiizow@ZaLs1BnF8wd54fNCkBlUFmx28KqryVRTbDiVt9nQeY8Uh05BbpUh1oSjgvJWcwv7N3cnhwz53vQWPj093tgwEO4RvPl5dLgupmsl5oRnSyfdLM9zKBg/ltRz8fgYnUa688wcHZrjG1p5YdCTltniBWiLQ0Z8W20mnGKgRGhWUcOr8XBSrzw9q6fq5XgJ9w@e7bElUlvXnpiClD05FWM5C7ZzVwaI9dJ0BPYadBTvM78EP8hDJgQJaKJDeQrhJnVv3ggjICzX6BYGse1TsFR9utLbvmk4qPgjI9Ot0o8hIk2@7h3up2ZNqOfKE/Ehc37fUSBWRlY1maKCG87jIqRJELw20T3WT0l4C4HYIHnHRbpGVi/mVtclKp2TCTK92no9s2RWZAZ9ruH0/IF31bo4dzuXbdZl/W@aQ3P07i1jhRW2jLdnPebqOfXVCh5tVRhqFSmy9RwRrMjgJqkaPZMZ00jLIq4ns/Hwu7zAUmSgsXIJT0BMUSlb6oVUiCflgkqvtlqvOJVcuVdz6mU8qxekK0FaTyvo8Bg6T2AtfEG@FtSxK/15fLbVci6ZN2iOYJQUnf1gdPYD@3ec4RJ7tmm@nLYZS49wsxqeIdEc60qJLglHypRQ/pEe0SEeHY@I03Qxzra0bMgBYD8Dwqo/pPcoJT3KaYN@4JKPSEhFEmLv7ffSo/DUUY4mDCBIza6H2dkgOOMwCq77cNcR3w2t6lwa0/GoYyoGooYxidvJZ7KMRwAxo@LoVa0u@ZplmB3MBF4H@Z6isY0Nfk/8DXjTJB3u1DA8OviQq6MR1zfg06fFBEyCBHOfjm9IUHy062jgLjQFFdB5F9roLpEgiD64jZtd03Ekir8BCOCIf8RFKk3MYArBCuREftSP5g5Q2dzkuB5XEfAUJK@UR1hYhM3Tq4yB045vwhEmK9AE7o@uEJ0cV/CIEqg62W4VIwqf4sEJJbQMLWw@4pKqlLyq@OmOoymxaGoYLQwcQ8Wje7GBE1kw@nluQfMZsR2r24VMc1w8GqMDjXQcV6SfjtL3a5hmPco891dv@asT/hr355kah9Kg/x4HKsUDyYnrcbgbJo@DZW6lVWEkm2hQ06YGEsc4bPmusL4WuA17HLgaVSWnyshjY8JDjfm8nlH73GdhIk5E4JF/jfsL@s6Lmo9yORH2yWT6@JVEBVm0N1ZsJZmiUs2xu5u8c4p8kMxkwCZjPDrWN5Edb5TiyKRgJyCg4TQ@NdtqZQwlrYcch9qMXN14ImtCmNhUprPBDx3ealgz2kgMS5RmmhA3pPOFkA55L8RAEEwkNBa23GoYeSQij2JgMdRCmCw/tHirgUPRppt4BY8xvsdX2NgnMxeGS8z2fMRzPuSF54eRJxFETHdBno2mSW6Cxz64oyjUHb3IOO3RNMTZTOJFbJI3StPiR6bbOMu9EPGJOKMIOcUtvEc@AtPjAHpIvvOqED1vpJ9nl6TPDRCh@11ryLZwFGHQaSpp4jw66l/1UT8SqWvxB/1@FxcVSbC7ohPPQndHvoCrKWOIsWU0TTrAjTs8fAZN4vw4RNLYIUK@wv0fYw9/cI6XVOO6DapFAtaKEyp2oElbzojPV0CbWc7zU@EWG/h8URQG8@fxTPCa460HMe33DdPSJJDFfJByJF7UNm/fYrocj4Wghi7o0kqS9N2BbV7sfI7LtWt6blmPoexSrPbmtOWV8UEpQFLokc@BuFrQVyQptvRr8qVfFQFm2DPs6L8E2rQu8SpkaQt6DArog3DqW96l1dIk6diK1ngRLpIyLjzisWl34Jl87gZkK7xCGU/7@hm@2gUUhl/sn/lqsElLYRkJ16TGi8lQ1Zd2CxEYHihpu7j4S@sReKqf4wMj9awAkLKUYpNZoqVlkReSXXo4zwTYQLUksaWHCA2OG9gm1AxNVEldAMVXOcaJ8QvfYzmB9MyugYd8tVkZwNMvYwyEGQhXiu7KgyTWxD8pD0wULFxCN8KayQL3c6mtQHO3PBu47xjBVCsULZZ3qODTpwcn7ORw//TV1vEeA/PR8eGXB7t7u2z7a1rCxnVwUgjLnh4@A@4SLZbzRfFDcJC3TiCmTB7S1ouv2d5XR8d7Jyfs8JgdPD96dgDQAPzx1ovTg72TDDt4sfPs5S4trgME9uLwlD07eH5wCsFODzOUahhNGsdjh/vs@d7xzlOwbm0fPDs4/ZpS3D84fYGJ4aL9FjvaOj492Hn5bOuYHb08Pjo82WNYMGn34GTn2dbB871dDdKHNNnel3svTtnJ061nz6YKevjqxd4xoz0AsVJu70Eut7ZhqIopUTl3D473dk6xQGPTDiAPMvgsw06O9nYO0LD31R4UZ@v464wAerL33ZcQCDzZ7tbzrc@hcJJyD1agXnZeHu89x0wDJk5ebp@cHpy@PN1jnx8e7hKuT/aO/9/2rnW7jSM5/xaeojWQiBkSd/EqcGjzatGRrI1IWVZILjgABiBsEMBiBiIgmTkn@ZEXyAPkUfIjj7IPktSte3oAUKQvsb171udYHMz0tbq6uqq6@utvj/cPT2oq8/L1CRHs7clhXuF9U1Q1lAHUgu/wvPf25JjodvzNKawZb/@E4QweDPI7IAy0cheyHhCBMcoBewtEev3mPZaKdKAByKt3Lw7h/RukKVFrF6mAARP7p3YyqBCIeGp3U31z@NXL468Ov9k/xM@vsZh3xyeHHgzY8QkmOMZ4i/fAOlDpW@o1jhO0ix@BWTOac/M0nOr4SO0efHuMLZfUwAEnx8ItRLb9F0JzmMuljOUs6Q7QNxBc2w6U9vyrDyHiOc57Xhb7YgzA0f7rg0NYkQVEykk@vIVVZ3MG@cj@BiuN@Qg/UwgzrbAx7tS7/fYAz4qabOzguI46ebxzwwPzXJ1nPnPtivhRKEM2W69/u1sHQ/ekXvfyD8mZasZ9OcTL/blUnvQRceHR8kYHz/PnTPftFKF2lmQfk@LwcH8BUzL1lziyLbgOPVUqtULJhofwsWDtIop4VwSBo1E00llGvIciqZI8EPS7K@xAGV1dfLFZRzcoBj5SokEE//R/TH7w4mC9AOnMbq1SCY1Yakb3Y6ir4UoI2oD@EWSBbpuqLEZh@EPHLdvVoc1f7AwGLdfzdB5KG4Md2HG9e7I3ws5M9sJsfmos7SoLnHyk7W5SYcz2spBMybgUR9QzF/@px/TH061h7AZ0ilJV5IsW56S7xNkx4CivBKICT0/QIKPO92r3u@N3aM2Vq6u1mfcvzHueWxgOiHi0sOCdUb4L@vPighPABCNMDSBJV5AuSiUrjw4nMYlvIOEVJiK8fVqrr0Ja14EkoMiOg55dJ67Go@7Ebj3I4a/e7L7ae3t0BKITW7u6ubaxXssYlKzv8vz3PdZDOKkEEjaEdRz0NPpkzZJ9UHxopljI2gn7EwOXSpgQscv1oNFLxGswYRnpQCUUZNjdCC9l6WMEnhMiHRxFQBqPM5pfF85MYQA31VUPe3MdTEjFD0BXIh6QWJXelEZtgv9g2Wb66yluOiQMJCxG6LTAuWBdkNxzjnQkKBk3hLODSYqO5mNGXTM0IFcXhcfi4Vn6JbxtjWLEkYo4X2nYKSc04vFsK5QOm@jzzP4T4YWIo5fAvuDNd8Jv8Phe8OgInS6I4t34BMh4ZHKiPzpxOkunz6Tkix0fhmhpydS0rdCb70mjaO6J29gAfFizgZpygTGDvpopuGbwQGarpADXL3Oe@sSciiAcWE5NOFZ@A@cu6o6UUtM4IPJbo0soLsuAlTDVbkwdGZ3kvcGj0ORMkekX0YPK/x1psqD8bbA4ofSEWhZm34MoSaUyrcB8JaJ0b/SGgrWLkVDTfvU@KebWHpgr0zHZpZnw8RkggYzOVL94TyiFbXcBAZDJ0bFhz18TcXYVgOn0peNJdtwP6Tevh66StUIvFXPlFtYv8qR25fUeCv7wlMe@JqvCl5BVfcmGW4NmPZhMM6a8eho5XJyncTxKy@QAMROeuPSKg1JnOasss0zLAYFMshaclkE@ArX09s7duWVlIVqmZL/scGlCQdE72J75fhKa@UBx9G0aIJHR008JtA4BtdFMxsVHEOYaFGfZC7Gcpy1yhuB1sfENLhA9Lp2Q9ZLSlPuU4kCwkiSoMIEFRHHrFYG0tKzemNaTZxI51LT@bZ8x6UP2aukURcbvkBbap@GL6lUwhSb3HtZtZrHS8skgj6GJWBm7JSQ/Xo3bHAxGoDoG2G9oY7479YrqnTgdwn40HgncIKxn3ZF4JLTSD9Wg2sTWOy0zjIBOTYu6MR5GaBWJP6hL1yEGgDL6yKSwrlxgXs2jO9rp2J2sVJS7nXzZBpoQiigRcVutqx9/5FRMUEH4DImC3cgYFxSSSfXgvoOZfjeD0Q@49qMK1G@FLQMkahVJvkAepOM@QTI2Y@76cBCRRwOGAj0ghhIVdqSZOFRYozeEnSRsyUnALBFqlHry0@sxTKqDoaCihHGldmC@9QIMJlKpKkieBtuzUl2jpiwyuG7vNMYI3DO9Pa2c874RKc9ZifCfatURn1humqf3@CROfv9phLMH3uBetqig2GDUWXH/dF7OUfsQmO9dNxy1bJ8oaDKtYIjuNzJ9Bn3iRe06FPi@ZhBH4RQsgGapOylRGXX368FVv74/6AWd7qAbgJ2GcOgTlnj4OKVHHLDOaHAT0fU59KFlJWpNk2eGj2E4Nfxt9iVrFsRWFIdD1w5HiEfT3StGgSDPOcb4KbNeEX8PZ7HOTJ7VtSRTJn28lMLtKl7tzrzPKosy8849FiACbmcmUoKPiMZ07sg6W1qbS9D4XAKrjQ1VUIF3R0BeqsVbQCLahkm1WDdmLvzA7gRaZne2@Kw1ybcIS3CEOErhQYgX0EQuvc4HeL0qSJEvMCLguapslq2svIsyQTxBfJjeTe7qxu/cemjAL2h@5dkiblnECCTi2hpMKWJ7RUBBoS0U/dclGU2SGKRYtwOrUC9VaH0yW2r68/QualCEDyhFApc3x5U4I10wfPDKNbcOIqc@9XBRyamcR7AcqILsxm75boYN7wuPpcmPm7jsOUPBtC8lu1aj7yJVE6iEt2vORM/aTWYI5PtnTLX60FGbIaC/KKLMuu3BdbTmQgdMury@4rbWYATC2JmhnoR65KJ4MMw9kHp3yo6FCGuLaN30vHvjfJnZfFgsl1tEWn@Kj9NaZrY9M0yTphhFlAEPoflKz4bNZ4k48es43/z69B463EWzJD7KLCpmvFs893FR/IABu3qhMVOK2o5gozXz/qwOHa/fLUGkTDav6iQx6igy6lN@tIqaIZOh0sMpRNwnbZ@hRwsoh/W2gHb2@NxJ1NlgOA1dqj@lwCqRnoizjmcyQS4N2xh8gShwrOEaIWUUzkl@Slt5lUIDwYLxAxeIWnFYSPxQ7MFNBmuGjwjMv@3WMVqogpIInnbsCAeD0W8IRiD64tyRiIf6tFC5qHFJE1MSWBWU6nMl6ePk8POsPqFS5kgBU3wBKUyP5mTT1cN79Uv7AumgBM5NnyWQt5zHznhqBVoD/9if6hPUgZOqJGdqRqUnQp1EA8wFsFI6vZDNVdT@uiPmeIxukGkEBgS/dvHPiuRA9O31sqE2Zpm0ppjEE3LzbPNUYYezJAzFv5H8MhVZ1SXDFQoIucWQ369ACQhPSq3HTQFC1rE5L9VQGSPI6FdwWsJLQjdN4jkXfEeiSoLVNStFeVGKLbuMwsJCQLFYnCZpCOgsi5MkpcBCt7AtVoqNxf1JUoBCrHmfKQ5DIaOSpqEZOSYgPFJrjUQ5q6h8WTiYPq6ueamPhr/p61bZ@lqe/Qr0MS08K1Rmv26WU19T1Var6aypnEAPz6419RFI4dkNNlLhl/1HJ09s6HITE2oZGSktQ@Kw@2hK3aDdVvw@Utt05lrrGLo8@@C3Nr/qfCNKClz980DqSmD6a7@8szowVTdEkP0JdU4fZXHZHiSF1cGVHnuFhq7G0TPwA9qkHbTVt6dHRylQ18ZUxxldh6O1crmMPNywMex1CDV6krqDUjp1qT3u9UrDm69H3zZKJPrx4vpeNHiuDegQRgTmRFQcjDp8jwO2AZJi6oIcU0VTf9xu2xcm4AYljh2MGqcUrANF60/XxLx8e0r@HypS1tdL7CD271KZyXcTsJ4ppehdKMiNEcEfHL15BuTBF20MwzYbVVQYymUdzATLlufvfMIFBO8hocEiFGLvUxKd7LwIe71BXr0bjHotxAF4dDub4ejIzlDmJLjBSGd3xxGhzeZV@KHbs04NYxKb1bE4vS7pWyE0vDtC3L8JO4eToeuc/dmBVQW6vILdXEGY6bxyOo4nmO8PKJb5EJr9oNTXwdBtEp1mE8NKLxM4eYIWPavkF5o@qSQeucSEZvenRqIubm6RoBig6x6pAhqSnoaXenJHckNc53xSaSMNy1yGtAkRVR6WAw@S/X5S8UPcbj9MKBKaPw/sby4QaQuAZqBMP6AngmH/UwGm9dEMXAjrN3jnxrzcwQx1zJDJPG36f7lxd3d31ZPhyora3d2Dh0JB7e7tqgN8sbenDuD3Hv5e8qtrazWWuQfeJ3i5p1/eqj0ogxycK82r0QH8hG8@ngrDYG0c4icl/0m@9qTub@/UotLZ7h4e2oenv/7bf/z13/@ztCs//gt/7NGPsz@bRMVisfSk@enJ0m0Nf58dXOSeNM6eDC9ynRpyGYr7t6Mo6AVW9GixmbnnhFSr123cdWrKRM90IwrVxHBJF/7xfbDAfvyRn87j5HGUPCImapI96A2vAsquqIQdP7ebW1qCp20/9y858p3I@8C8/wjvlYeynEATiLR474/aPdk/PrZhx1Hqk/beDhEjB@@5FLwc2bi6zOpbAgtnqlhUFwV1aZqHYR51TphuIpuZ3Jh/lUbq3lFMDu1di9mAm9Lk@mZ3PG9MXUcd0u@065wvPwvEUnnaes57aFTGCgg8TF/jWHU594rdh@bitpdfOKusr10UstlsxlyIVm@SmKPahlSXuSBLb6ETPgMfwxrClIG@0wV1PtICCkRiZLN0XdZSk691c/toWpPFxAZ3Nmfp8@hvoo5kjJhjDzeDKaCOhQYfXUGmojGdwkDdYPrQPTxoAB2v2ybBpfiS5GgYNrvtqQl5wBspktphrcQjc8uqPXdiTjmjhiP9etxOCgSCoBZAWD1Y6GyBTLwBpO2StOM@6t@gbswz1aWAf6tVGmATEDQc9KadHlTmUihVdAPSCSjvyWD1@vooHdbAORshaD2hzGgesCSWF9vdCNEV0W/iDhneD9VDTC5W@Hj7l9AoYT6ghiP3w7XxKIjb63MA0aANj7Dg4yk63sIiNlzBJVUYCo1aNI71/XIiB5aHnqeGnBKpCr@TzXdiD3JBkj0sF90JTAjvxgw9yYlvt4XThni1HxrSgg3qyUxyaK6Y3TfQKq9xrxL3KYEomLJId4mBaJiqy17/0vSfdzcjvI6w6OgquZoqxyeAxDLV6OPyVB2fBXDYuUo3j@EOp9yTPYiibgOIBV2UYSIIRD48MIJSz3MZrky4BbcDkcD4anloZpTdP81K4WRI5/O5vY/QtdvXXJBKiBukuCcW4t4dYhwMROTBr/6gXyCR2wjjbpMDKLn2x1oWD3FfnLYpqWF3VwTGQ4D9NANMNZxrdCHZLqahTsohOuFhBZz/V0b1Dohm4uYVES0HR6BBhjnM6JwnREpKNJxABaSJIm2k@G@h4KMUY/bCTjdO5ckLAgOHnXMvbjXpcZJfYoNt6s5QFg9K6J1mIxIuhd46NAMFr/4GgnbTk8PPi3hPdwZXNb540uTkLtF5us15/jDySDfHbjXMYCAfTt98eoRoccW1jkDkEMqzlWZVlYzCZ2ugwqWJLC@W6YAPFSDSYpYmhTOgRnWGGiBOZ6ZBIoXLqeItBkbmtldyklEz5OXhYpVgTnhrftEtRSa4zZgjPZ/@v@tNDWVjhOeTYfJBKuQDWKOTgBODozFb5MIZeBNqRV3A8UA0jsaISMeBLLKiIIRNlyepValpx0xVuusywgXSlIaEjwI/z3L2WM5k1f1Ncl@kcxdyfKTrkz7Y5VqaztCT817y9REv5pX1NV0un9iirTf6dauPlsnJLBMwoUdHSE7La9BG8mBADN2xZAbndhFraBteS3ndZ9EsQLlMFU5l0RaNpLNjghYQiWMVdsfx4Dj@9XV6wpaWvT7zkq5bBb0gADVYVITAK8kTPGL0sfdrmQUoB7ogCDh@LYhCeM5kWPMQC9N5FXX2BhO3nD93zp18ZX3Lc8hONnpYthmBZZRthoyWhlc2iu1JqIzk1/4QsggfNbqtVtjXWKyQVWozn@pS7Bm68z8ZcRfxDbcOCfHQsWR5VIBBpBdCa3oejoLOdUCP3wxOR8H0GBYh@vm6z@N5guW9gcUI72SiL294ju62QNVwbtFOTnjiQV2kqKgANJ9mTKoBI/FZ6sICAoRzBOA6Tf@jdGctMtj9Z9@F0Z5p3YRBvWQNJeIg6kveOLnM8IW/13gjbZ3fAW@61o3A8kifZq6pFh0BP@gAYest52BVv4c7PWE/tQ@hoYOF8fjaaM6VVz1g0LI2uT7flQHHQ1@a1keXYtjEzav69bgXd6Vnc93S/cJMs3cfkzmpr6u@4/5jchnO0s7qB5Z71oVZmtgyJKgSKogRpkux7EdNbuo/uR0TpUFMFYb9qK4Sf5Rva58ZG9bud7Spgagc1oaNNk6xnxnL3IDctUyyzirT68cp4wPbAUTBZiwP6eJpEs239hjjCCNuCAkTM7i/hc3@t2zk8hvabUiopO1SCc9kGZbY@nSqIK/KsoltWbXAKXzz@OA6FMtWzAnLeLVujWMwzd/dYL3HcktpfxapdNS2rbs8Tk20lHKo4zUtcholhlZmexSor7YyYmsSJHKGAozAdJaSbvlU@kKxwUYJpOQ2zyrZWmMyPV0g3qCIucUzb9SIuU@e1t6MBkRJgadaWqjK6pYsbBLvi169ZAXTbU3rlLbKrpIFNNFZFxjhhg3uJVQ4T6jKzyMUt2sRnfjLr0amNAHSVLrNZBaxrxEdEpplz3VzgmhOLhHhHhtFeKaMBYpuo4eggUnDZouDAdSa/ZZWhpfVbgfEYloX5sDwIHnHVg8bkNHMkXHjiONjCOMRgupmQbvKwP8IcAxS6hodOikPCKispYxJROfDkBpEb@ONEMgCVcp6GYkZKmX5mqDKRsWjSh5QE57A/QXqPYtB3Ippzx1@wwWFVI5lVZcDhPevfrTW3eGWTvVvoUsaJHLilGbxvDwc4qGC@7zUpaxAWbgKilee@pkOavKVVHkNQj9PKZt5BE1gTQMx9aAyyr0iDt4ohG4YRE525yZhWGwfakf3H8n/rWmsYxWEA4yCUNbaAepndAU0D7BoCHSQlSZo7mmUA1KbszMLa0lUNVIXibQpTtYreEWW6oUOITMqtEpHKrlBdRRbXsWFXlPtIVLZhdmUixCj6M2graOwiY5w46WKPMsfLG6HEpQtN3JDs/igpCkyJa7s7iwtKWkbuaxndIyFhn6KUNyOFDHO@3LeYoZ1QQjhSyK8LCkwTYzWN1zof@AEkiKZnUuLFREUr4keknhoSgndx31D@cXUoayfow8dhhjMnDcimpBENdgvSWsyP5Wgs/S8h0nJofe3w6U/aSQeyqpyb/ddvMhr8UaF12J77ZlGJfQ24OqDf7tNPudLB0uT9Uct24evH/H6S24K@IcZlM4rxAZEAKR9FHty1/ijxK4rRnGdr0034hftOAm5a7VgOQZhSwea8mAnxhSDpCw66wBbAhj4SQumNtK5ehGFYGJiU2YtM8md2GWKDDPL/NWoBESpthzjfgTFUXgRneTEratBk3EBYIHC721CBSC7tsJmERpEnPEMf8qZykdthilsy0zmHqjlulQrfZD2UCdYx9obBfGDVKxkS44D9lUfQaJAy5rlw6iYUcc/XSV7iF62/GC9LLtMPu3lRD1bzg5Bt3j2M8v4bfW0xEEL5Tim5Q5OVHLgk8kBJIYB6mGEceLMF6llb7n9fLXvH@rLH3VhWP7Dqy/LhvzNtBKznCgxzYVKTJJAcjXR8Ub5THoSDzBt@2QhL4vaw/UN0vXBvNH1DRbWxzexqySdZB5Qtfh6QbXxzUByGEaVCsn/uLAilLU8py8dmduXyp2f0DzeyTL87B/L8N/3MlwytEC00XtWGmvo/zH2fw9jj/iVvc3yZrn@q@37mneOzVjOzH6rUs5jVdn5YuN8clA@n2ytvv5LNs7uVEvvRvA3zv4lu76Z5Ud4gF/P9K8P2Z3sNiZbv81OS77vw6OUsnsEpex8bcrEVNNt@GdnTZe7Ps3uFHzK/mN2Zx0eKtUqtOR8crh1Ptks4/9O7Y@kfti7K0b5uKvUIWHayILAe4ESIk9m@SBKity3VodjZAFtjqcdpLjyQ6EFajAGz0yqm2XRVYCBGPzhQyj3b2nYDNEfCT8mJkQTPnGhYR8kVo8zwQwwVXjwh6qg1V5UrwRwQmNNoJaQNFpdPi2u49b1pWBQmAYYvAlSMzmUG8wLlypGeDP8u1P@wjF4FM@dFAhGem9TVsVNWRX/N6uG0/hq0K8uQLXPqn0YrjhU30fclqjfHQ7DmDX@TtgPRwRlAt1BRQev2WvipYS97g8c/vdcF66aVFD9@6jOZ3O4oOJwqpwnX8LM6l6TVfQRZqV@xv2x9VX9CwQ3XtiG52T06ZpON74aN@hCgtPR9Dh@TUgUJQQ1jxmVogS6XKN0HWDgAMH4R8BikALEwWjcL9HFbqCw4VkZxN6/Dn6ApuFlstC1Vh2SobP/B5dubo3CIR1xmbTbDl2TFPZaJ@EwGAWMWIdR8@OgEx4jEg8MRnTloPGUVd/Q4ZrYhiY2xhJRHPRwuQ@rwOhhJPujnD7@SaRVCo8b03U9Dp5TFyFEstsp0qkJyOXw0QK6Irw9GMRJej41bjLQz3QOwmODQeKjIbg5mPQIpDn2f0U3YkUpeUHtSH5KpckLqohaM1JdvEYDexX2x9fEO@Za27PK8wvBrPMr1vXiFPG6@VyulHccJCgOkzibK5v4Zcyxl7QvmRHoANMPUKy5JZCQB2RMu4XXYClE0aDxPQEtoVSCCYn8V9TfZNpTGD08orO7H3YCkhU3DQTjgbetbkQJMGep8xF0dyZRPsWqjXEnKvJcoIMV3Sgah2sbm6vUIFrxddLWoJlKWi1ByaNgNC1R467i657pxVZ8pXrhh7An0SvUbILz5UlJfIY3mgXjHoW1rHvEOkDKVE@BCu5Wnt8dHB693D09PMiDmrKGySM6lmTSuhZx@fMKfW/3EKmB2Qiz8PQtNtZXmcndKJ/7Ej1y3PQvbbKv2A3WBURREdeA7tDN@ZRN4iy4YDVEs73fyZvtcIIa0qjRON2wKWO6asLRxNUzP5vFI10R1pVFFkwBG0Ae7Jg@uT3qgeCZS3SnrAAKiHSrx8CRPZSfyLnO9uNCwcyp5/RUAMFaKOywk8XZ73XB8My9GfdT0jZHcydQORByuP3Pou1xjuRC0ampKx/t@FrTL9fMub0P7tj7ZK6kbmMrXCbc6WBvqsfPHcvJNAcI4lGUsz4y@T//nfNqtwmITs@NPbx6QX30NXJ0kYX6Id9V6@aiJgxWDNk@FuNwEu8z0qcf10yGxqA1LRK4VmsfrOqW@9GuY@h6n2CtXllp@v4z7xNUORoiAugQhGF4CiV6NXzXTr0zR8RK5@d9vIB6GY/ufffq5QsYcowTC6P47M8Xy09K@VzO82rYhcCn830Hr1/9Cb38I69I3v6j0eBa6DIKTCVFGO3r6Kx8Qa3PO9i1Es5CkJydMJbeR3vT06DzDWhLbi4AEmBYEh2Mg0HpbgdyvqyGsUmoc@HlLDaNfCc9uI73qeNTqqtR2K6xr@I28j@4Ha8Ww58ru4o1qMKvVqn0GDL5GNU0Q/VuH1brF6evXvq57UBhqf6CWZFbaRjmAEYhhnHx1S5eR5ViHZAqxFUxn9YjhoH/VnLOTrov26VgJ1e7vb2zPS8ZTxeUn1zCwC13nBeOG/nzQ1obJVwwHYY@vuCl7avDUycPeRGCBV/2cXmbktDiQ6y@roPZDSUFLYHTE0zj@6tLS/QOs4wj36@Wyx4iotxCaRHeHw/F8sQa1W5Hgd9yDSGDYXfBbUnVYrXEB1miUmW9Wl7b@GIwgiXCxwvplyIQIT5aLR@68XQJdMPQ1zcvLYGeDKup/3h1efN1d@@fv9s6WT9wm42vK07e@T6isP3R0G7AKLgpsloEMnYkWLvUCDy52AxKw@CHQWm1VW6C5lnZaIUba@Fm@dlmcy18ttXY2tpqtlc3G62tjWBjrdkoIdg7ZSled/ugJTnM/lht@2HV3qWYbVbLW@12pbK@0Vrbam9Vy8@erTY211rl1dX2ZiV49my9Vd1sbDU@r7Ul7cmAgNVyF9eOWQn89G7lLjMn2yW3938)

JavaScript can be disabled in Preferences (Ctrl+,) > Security.

This answer uses [CSS hack for Safari ≤ 7](http://browserhacks.com/#sa):

```css
.selector { (;property: value;); }
.selector { [;property: value;]; }
```

Code in polyglot:

```html
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

## 279. [Befunge-97 (MTFI)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/befunge-97-mtfi), 13145 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)[-'][(7aat       r[>]77*,68*,R@'_)(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退     @[[[["472"?]]]]*****<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@   nthie@O252<nthneo anet/112\    #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"         ; L        ;              x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnn >"972",,,@_MnMMMMMMMnMMnnnn #9##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>> nMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                     
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>_             #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                    @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}


















































































































































































































































































































































# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
 xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51  ata""[ x];#mint}=>+8;dnu?1&&1PLers 6 4 >8370::$/  \0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>ExPrdisps94 Cr u Uithw;har#8doc""}2:2FACbody/'='~-<d  *   
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}#@[[[["272"?]]]]*****<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8                     \@,,:1'<
#  |!o51  ~nJQ ; ;#p'34'                       \=#x=4; print( 1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2    )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print (47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                :~-<~-<$~-<<<~-! `=> $/#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25    >[};]+ pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*^e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*             <e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dc@NKdiD4XJj9B/uSAnWLoEiABCVSFClSpdLHLfWtKqlLurduN8VigSAookQCLACUyFKportno9c9dsx6enon2vaOb9uznrV3JmK8EztrT4wdE2G/TjjmyT@gPC8bjg33P@g952QCBClSUnXbEfuwkAjk58nMkydPnvw62TL87i9@kcCHHbm98VnPDVhg@QFre/aF5Wns8Zg9Mmy/kF@VJAy17Z0N@5YT@GUpwXTGHOuSHTim3QY3FrjnlmO/szzwyzM28Nwzz@izoGsEYLEhFtu1eu/77wNmuv2@4bR9CLnK2JEBnp2hec6Mlh94hhnYrgNea4x96fSMfqttMAhheQPPCgh8gQEI85ziTPsUGXvmer6FyZuW77vouM7YptUfBOMaWEoQwvBs9@n2889nIm8w9rkBORv0rNFMXvQce2lbXnsmhq6zr07292dd8@wL1XXY/s386avsS883esYs/DW2PQzcg2DWvcC2zyzHYHltQ8vPehbZY8@4EWWdeZbR7tg9S7Mdk6msa/UGlsfQhXVcD6ossHqlXCnX3J7E1EyMW5p4zoCthg8zvDMfPN0LC4wW1MTAttqs47l9Zjj@JaSkb@Qm4RHsxjQ5mJBBIDT2xofYbYv5jj0YWAH3hOJaHnlDyqxnO@cSp74jz20PTds5g3AW4HUwDKhMvmRCtBobCBrW0MAShAUeDLJw7PateF34QLyQa39gmXbHNjlyrFFgOT6U19eYDXV3afd6rG31IMIEuplhvsuGfsyp1TO6mqlJiFxMhfXPe8xm5mDAuBcUA7K0nysxq@@@sdk78O91fTYa9Jlv98E7MN1Ox7LYO2vQheis32bm2JTarsTgMQczpYtsyxaEcSwo4c7RdwB3AaLU6UD22qwVCwd5oXxTqQ3HBRR6zDH6nCLMwZgwAGCiGB3X1dC97Vq@kwzYpeuds5ZlGlh0TMy3zjrGsAcp2h2sEqAF22d9F75QkQ6DbEHkAPGBsDExaW5BMJmwiq0BNE6sYhdJBuo7rOlLzwAa8XxRl4HdBwqxg6TPLMO3kWtBFN9y2kQdg4ifuVDaeMWzCxsaH6Bi6BFs3/KI/Akuw1IASCOiV@XSswOgCizFNjuyDI@deJaV4rRq@aYxQEqNJwmJuZhCgAXRiDg3N5N7h/tJIFIeQzMGQJTe6sm3vyUZTKuy5WYFflVZrkh7z3fZ1fIpmjnfBEIeeIqRYtUPzM@enlrwG@mt7Jl3LQFUCbDSY1l3EGQNdQAZVAPIYNZAI5rUi7w26MUSZpszdRBrOjxUG2oDGAH7KkMlM4eehxx@glTjHArdc50zwCcU1hs6vMqLOagCoL@2n2HWhYU0wOvIvSQMn3SBQuAfgsa4C@90CKHQ7UBzFBgN0/Xd3pDCQUw/wDYJWIGoCPGgw75iHcPuYRTwR1A8157lA3FinKHTxprv247V1liYDeI8HrTHC0jOAKDkAK2hH@MvlCkIDBXhUlHR6@Nv/k777AzgbJum67UFuX4FxG5S92hQZqGDY0iwrmP0KFsQLoOp8@iQwIXRs9vE6QxnLJKgTFCql@6w12bUUC9taHJdAxiuBUzCDCxO5O4wgDxmWN8451zR5pQLBe8bLahYSoDSpmKr7NEO1JIJzZxoRu0Pg06JqYM9lvSzr5StsrK1dGpB5lJaamU5mz2rAMFpK@QEtuRtlPPV9lR38RU7A0IZDrB87QwQAXPcS0E4urqKZEKcB9Ble9Pt1RpZ5jCwsHaB5beoJH1jTJFj7KVAMID1nBwcYhVBPXo912iLOn6JdOJfAmPtspYBzDxApo14iucU40PeushbHB86MevtELIEPAlwNA66rpNnqslks@pCACU5VfxkJum1kikNOxolVbGrptaxnbaS3IRmVAOcJVMVs2rW7XKjMhM9ngcAc4lgkNNYipmSsfWd2C7yod6gi0IEBHX8ATBRD0tqGkAOPvZUAchpGdYiQqXuDVgFMblLKwl4ahl@RBjUxngbwvgqcj4BYdImppum1Y61TGjVgODAv8Feey52@ZQnrFDgBQ4mapyBWAeReUG2eUF4SuQyXaRzoA4HobUsVlJbNlA1th9g0oKIY2WD4Kt5HgagcaqP1SiSCnRTvL@ftACsaYP1ob17Y2ZayESAm1i8h8BEhtSgfBBmmdthOTVfKEw3mhttJvCy2@p3geu@y97aNLDw8daBnIN1QHbuGc7Z0DiDJuE6EMUwTWsQCM4DJfED4C2zHQg5qqI31PyutPxoNm3qFUKZZ5IGtR@qPdG3GcguhCyugqCF8hwX8FkbGqVJzWA6dQhwMZO4/BqDTGXgtbwgC2GXDkTGWzk0biDgy64NrfSScudwRsd7ldnkwSmeOrBqtRMljZnRaw/zkpaNnDAbC0GoWKM34UBviaBqUw5U@XGH2yEbfn8OYDfKInD2mKuWNTSgvTtg9l3HnQMUEBmBxSDTPrweQLQ6RkkXeqJQjqLGGom/URVBnQHXgJYP9NcNgoFfBsZvB91hSwNKyZ5444Pg0EFiyQbe2A5cbm713Fa2b/jQPrNhCllz2LJHMwUit6gO3/jSBUhUHZ9VGbJeoDol2fGBb5L7DgaOeckk5RAI/pYhIAXSAFFKxydWvA9M5XjsmIo8RZRyhsnYduUUGDBihJpvoTQ2nc034DSbSwwWz4yWxVBZ3zPJoMaETASPwSlb0oOpot0zj9IDWYZXx@j5FnydYa@H1qHDuZzCO/8Uu5IePADWplBydn/Qs007aHJf9vChEBLYEgzcUA7qoBCUgjgPxAhZA4YCYUTvw0NrgXtM0quSgoI8uJ5K2PI81@PpBl0POnVywGBSHKnP7fNhewarDrohOmUcQ6CAbAYg8cL4iss9M0QwjanZvpclEVNIKhifM80qkwU8SuoG6ZAr1pgsogkhsSqyFqtCBXOU4XAh8Fxs8djCLV74HbePXRt7SeIjjgdgoG47OGEhcbGCpApjrlQRCRQk/SeT2hvXdpSr5NLSUrKcrIG4sLS0BaZNNG2hKQ2mLTKpZMJwGpooRoZM6FunGOjWSF7XQ8ijVAN5wQiHOO/sgWLUy@XVRsao6@Kbx28KiAy6Swit4gfgJFPVKhpTKbl2CQXVWp3p0u9gl39sevZAIOFbxoXB7QILq4QGoFrXw7qoIM5vx0m/6lmaD0Mbs6t4ydN67rRxenXaTp9eJzMYO1Uxqi0oFKSn9LUzzx0OlFyqvlZW9UYqVV8FUaxVTeaSK4pSUmFQCuOq1GelVNrg2FaSFogCyulpEpAq8FM3ux7BG2XyqVSEKsgHSnswclCS2lUJ0m@lGql0EuKmkhkYiFaTScCMiUjwqdBI@VMIOnzxBUfMTjotEYHCGBt/N2QJcMMh/HT0o@G7d8i4OYxWRGG9ocHHgwMRIHvghGE19JwZgoderQ7DTmQqjc/dDh/j7eBr7@m@ZI2otj4/3N97UaVkuoZ/DgKVeoZhs34A4oThtTVoR71h25LmhQGeCSZzkhOcDcHEz0yTqS6jYKrJMxHrK022ABowWpwS0Fym9vrTRfC7kN@dqTIQEHKnmLcJb2aYJR58bp6iJPehu9o5fjo16dc/B2GKmX4PJz9UjxcArNkV7timTwLYoeG7drvMDmjE6YB0DbQFwnU7mtlwXEfFjiAcnLrxhPj0DoQgNxQ1UYyyp8Ig4I49ggF@AmeHUPbDARiQEDAwQJgDQ21Le0nMTWbAJHH@DUZi84ZCR1yK1Ex/0jphtAPGQc8wgYVPgzuV2SkABA6Uzc73SVVuAIaR0dTAiGYl7iojyJGm4SD@2jaNuoe230X0wkAKu0CvA1jFITeOJQlrB8wEEf8MMG2NbNEXQQs/xihPDF9J4Vh0mw@ykMpwgICZCuciSXp3TXPoWTBQQF8@@cP2nAvbcx1EsrYHoIEVVbAOZoDPQy@Q0fb2QX53MX7nAQeM3XDWY7iNQ51FrulD63LcnnvmshUIgKSpaZywDxycs4VOOzAG0KLsd4Sg7TPXGc/QoGVFs8DFVSR5PjOFIbMUXnsDvQCbX@hJgAVlPj747h701nohl4P8h7YcPVEhY1Bmy4iOJpsEEOsaPaQbrMnvWoPu2JsiJ98Vs0ABTYVSw@TzcgbIz5Ar0cLfUdR4I@cu0M5Dr3Zomlf2PRoQ4VTkYLyg9FPCB282UMLEjDO6hqiYAnqjwif1i4zrNDvFt8Kqu1A7fTcwsl9pwKLxJeHwQLWZ7GeTS8msquJbJi@Wr7Fs27rIIpeaQB7t4UzNHNgjyzKz6IudGwsNc9ETei5AzSk8Dr2gmPwb4iCKOVv@s3QaGTvlLkqbZxo6@ZPu0JIss@sy@RTGV/GSydBBdO22pQLmQfrFQVkUTaxxSYE7hDFt2@rZfTs4oFWInoMDN42Yt4ZcS/juAL@ZADiyLRiN8NmWSSeDKwWTPso54@FfACcnqH7ANI5Sz2pnVybQnrmu18WpLZ0mVPIR6vvCI@v6g7YWjAAAj7VH/bsf9vPPD3f3mkfbJ0@q2aHvZXt2C3hE22r2YSTfg@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@IAM3QvoHu4KI7zU8K9iO59XBKfSLJkjRxFwBIFxJVxzWuFjhvoGK2JT60WA6sU/HOe/@JIAvKVnrtG4Je4qh4r35Wuk/tF0OlMOefJ@VzFrqw3cV4lZ76mPr2aLQp7w2tu4AjeGsHja/Fz4d3wmhs4glfg8HANfz64GZ95QSNgRQKGa/5zYc14zAkYQVonSPF9AhO/Evkt2iQg0prrvTBSBHuDYPP1/@Ybv4midlMs/yM18wZyApLYUxfk56c2Llp0plqMFI3ATyU5nEaYnkVDHy67ZC9mRnbqhRyPx9u@7Zy7NE6OTM2cphewPUex@@e9mzE7MLKg11TQKA@hHLMgd36/1aHXnADYx87OQpIHTfGKnh56ViP7gj442TsvB9PT1lPJt6zOEAY92ZbtoPmOYOpGiUJ2Wi17UVDABO6eCL9zgpXZiyEMPPPamqaHo1xcJgIWzeecTw4OKWDLoDHb9FoHm0J@MPQCiCW@/@V7baiEm1XUNcY09IsMTce6xOpSOwtrTERFC73m1@6kkyfEkOkukKaB68VGLzLMB021r6pdw@vjCEtUNxAovoASbqE1nnM@9RJ@5ydSZoTk6TUV5th9Zt7YSxO4LvNh2Dypm5mVIJ4uDa9xEZYwwgfBtkWRPKx3XiPWiA8HY6IO9Dlzcjibv3DBhk22PATdYTDkb9zlcFeN2gP83dZaRchcwWjpFgjHRsu2bql/zzgftl0VZDwqMmasOCfspPQ0Tad2esY5NzbROL/4vICefXYGkoT4Lgp22YVRDQ1Hs5f0uYtEfGfoD9QWVFYAbYhs1Cr6t6Tg9fh7URBb7AWMDIuxZvfodY9Kj4iLyAWEOUI0bs9SY0izZ9DcM1pjHKR3P53KMEESbYD9VM10OreKHV605B3fUrU4PvaSFH9jY35svjGMo2TewCrLN4SpfOqYyiy2iN1RsdCH2X2jp@bbMeNC5h5OGk9Mc4LSjI1q9gwfSCsQ1WFdQPXR6zZyx07KhAGXNzHdQuyT7IQ7HxYtogsOJlq16fZsH5t2bxEznV13nKSJW/PoFZuMtuchtk3Skt9VI9N8vuCaAa5gLyC0e3A5vniMy/MxytHcRUgz3Uv8LZQyuu6Fxd/z@7x3c3N1D46l9ogkbHNu59K@2YuAE@/iaZ7VB@EfiIlmW3Ua6vLdGuH2hEJx8PZmLeBeKHrNR/753MIEZm@u@3TDCWdE4uO5ezYG3@65Pjum9224hIL5Pn/PbwZxtNuGo9LyUdw8P5rI1IBpYlJ2ATEYvTO3VyydZQ14LaSYodfBjkR878syI5an63ezvFC@ch1dfBf2FedZ7/yuuqOVDA83OMSMt3Tb8/ieWMNcXEAgUdy1NL9w@7kSxdSyfHi9qAI8s3tpjMPvL9EdLcJu2B0NxiSvg/iIETZKYAg8LsP/Mqmt3Z5a@3487QbY9bsKEavc854FvR@9b1Qpy@f0T4yh53L353Cd3tAaWnMZ3GHrjYUb/G8Zxdw/UzlRjGUxOYoTSDg1GoV6J8af98o1dvxou5XBALOFRn6neDSX3w1AsB/gCP0IDEdouBnxzBkOpip3ahTovLgdc91B2LLd9lQm0edTOVLpbiFsSvr3LfrdOjjjg0lcCquu5XI5IRTFprunLLcN2lajuG9s/p5KmFwmKU/CYs/pxYzz05jMvELV2@e@inOg9@NO@UUzChR4YyPr2I4VjPF9T0bbct3ep9Qe8Nu2jfIeSLG4RHRXLd6QpcSmOTaZNvFx0qXVWTRhwvsiMZoFxOGY/TZCiE/S3quGVRRuoIGezVhvn0KKTfnelQr08DQvxTdZ9BYLqmIyRtdK2vqtjZGLv27L6hn8Myqu3QZvQ1u9FV4krQi5mlbBcOWMr5VN1l4TMyxrMAZk2W0YFHWtvkXWW0YTRvvN0A8/CwONXPzN8dZoZXJRvIENPMLB99S6XEyKClwHhnGB4Z1ZOA7q4fq5cF3El8P597nIPegbZxY/U3Yb45xMjeAOaz56nBjnT5KU@f40E6LxTSK3kwI0pnNr7IffuQCfjU2oz2H/7lm@mXZv0pamuxq6lp277HCHmOh03a7Ttbp8z1BkW9Q8gCIDfhrwtkJA/s@6JiP@FN/PFMdsz@317oNZ5I@cW7puZ26e9vCMWhuifhLcsdECD/G5c/YQunlCEPX3i9pN1xpCb@W7gTuwVLItCtrDySX@XsRFw2WgX3bW6tYZBcBI@P1l4Zt3RTwz3GAwoE9z0Bv69KKoKh0tvGXIxqfOKUmiS@Z6Z9o7t9/ShKO2z7/PoMIXMJsWnnPBLUycsq0zt2V27bsy3bKMwLHPs@EcE7feOuwdxPBkM3UXnbWeDej1xhrSSzXuf4yfg0WVLqareMcWGeZTQZntDD1vjJQezkXTlAFtyZqcWZ5wlen9GdFkMV/uQMOiXImVxzneJEPgzr1wh9otay5ioXIhWZLUjhK6auVAzNEXzltNbR@NtanVVf5aJE3NlJ8yFVsf/pSJV7GtgqYg7dj8MLhP0dTUYvfcLs7pDs/8m0ySLwu0QTDD19za3z7DU@D3qHxe0dCXGY74LKqDfC@L@@Xh24TaHFq3LvEUbl3joXB6TzVcGz5N@EC9DhdO2PXsgc/fTO3k54oeN5etb4Yazx97izprWx2@CoOmu2TGvuvhqS0QTlTTs3wTJ/GRt3NJjPMxxz0DHq/22CRwGHZuEW6ulM8liajvVL9@bp0ZuKXzqY27O3tzKAWgzi6Y3wX020PDt789dANrLrzZRfO7wD0zzmzzyRTmQ2AhRsW@P/6ZagrodBP5l13bpwMzoeGWiSskMk62SGdNGDnMG/LNLBREx8tvn5uJiVxivzlTD1i4Lz0y4FIF@htz05q3BuAOaPA5JtNt0/92QNO74juXquZvPLgt@cthfzD0xWd@6rQ3KD453j8nd//SBlapvgUOzbpGL5g/gR6b3gXpTXSmE@Mief67ds89Y98t5RgIeyC8oXg/h@AeQ7d@ZATQIpw5BExpL@Dls0u0OHOici7pvwWasFaZajt2cPssURAYMNoKv1gY3gHhsc/sU3xrjz4VgnoyHyNPb5VkQQYYmz1UK8D33fms5VnQhXJlBtEWuds7MxNo8ZgO/6Mx0j8Qp36RmLUTrlaIfsexLuPjv1sXncrY2brOMFDxfMGty@mTTqZ4aydTZqNSMUYrTPn23rMvU3GSoT24d4m4Fowxh35vPDEt3A4xQ4m2A1LeYuY8HTocqOxapCXiBe0WvSPO9gDPr1EfsOvOG0wdjT0ruPdoDHqUYX/XMnER9M60n7vPQL6Dvm0AXLj/wuLH06aYy/yIGO2paxo9wE/7zmSOCeyczmMybjcGVgvqtzcxzRfY5gHeNQJjgYBF05E0uIxMd9KK3WtZ3huaZ4yZF42XpzP0xBrRwGUxwfAGqQamyaVynPGbai6zK0b@wHUd/iaunIOP/ux27gP9Bb3uv/iv4Sbqqe5w7vhvurSHkfoBfnRyUXE9q@X2@BuLsKAndGy@z8HwbMvPPrWd4YjcimtMBXFu/giJ7ybOaeukAgYaUrjEGm0zxl1zgnfODMNATr4wfNqBMH/wM7Wl@f77nbqGZ7q4KicMn7gmFzubdgdbj/Zs850SLaiYETA1wxyKU053ZbXXb/XptXDwEqvtF1YLz/616GxqYIzmSZbTZ9iE48wpspCtYeMvMuUIhkepu2fMZsd20xi3B/Qipn45l1DC5J7blvnOSN1rXBVrUTRlnTVoCDy3UU1v0wMZqGepQRc3fWaD2@bSw/PBcxZkhn0L18CnV4IWkpLrd4kO3Pmr/hGr9Syxcxx3LUKjD83Ib9XthYSK4OH/8PG3stAlN4trqD1hOFLPgJHdvc8AMj/0HPG5D7EduX7QsUeHA9SL5XqLOAsWqwBR4MMbAZpWFhUCas8Z9vh0yFlsW1m/TUM9EAw7Lph6xLwDS7WcC5X0RY1ulsj1SOVNdhsVrgVWWxUTJLisoT4N5bIomPjOWcuNs0nc1apnOWJHxTWxz3Ueci/9aFUSPNSBT9/swD86eHp4og18/ZZJTNyrOLR7uMZIzS10A7SQaeFU2BvDi63D8q13eOAw@/hYV3eeHmgYYEG6fC1FhQ@uE059Fu/cGHSNlhUYWWPh@Al9rWC@7Pjk5NnT9OQANlN2up7bt1Jx753j4wywHvat47ne8dj70FQ67mhh9IM9XU/NoeUvHVqrXMQ156S0CNKJBaNgoMwn/CzwnXKX6Q6s9sl4YH0FnSpybv@eyRcXFvK5cWGfYZNkGwsRRa2WbWjFtVRsXzoM8i0v@i6qz3N7gKzTpE@WfxZuk0GJYjXrrc6XKm7biTAr3bCc2CHxaZH03E1qDWwVWsZZF01Zw/9VM6br@iI8HxsdqFdWWFhZ0wHmSRw99@Ie69iWGNeokZMaAFWp9p0b6NfVPvDxLL5wWUA4grG1aHuOOOVH6tUivT1@Rpw/BTfbEwo@fC3UFSgO65LIE46JwdEwzSFO4wK1aowCKoqRTqdSkoj1BDr/Pioiw0g@nTkH@quwXGhEoaQLHJ3Co8oRhS0bbLPK8oUcS6UqXHsPsDDg00Orwjp2CBr6BfvMgSyEOSBNaihgcA0aPoORdBDCrdfZ8tWonCvr16jQoyyzRoPnGB9KZG80IDVoL3j0@rLRqC4nVTW5nDx1yiyXjIJbPd@aH9yYCguZxY/IcIRfriLRJf2GETYrXOkUiHKooa1rOG1oloKxQfk9rjqJ6@U6wcMJf/mHbaG4jhQ09m3f6AFCUP8k8Niue7nF0w3RNRgYHmkhI9VIPa61Sd3ZFvrMuL46qK4v909KQmmWUHYJliM@0x/lglMOblLAM/ABJwyem@g8s0g4ihUWynR7w74Dg4h20PU1dmzT8fahNzmwJlSAOoGHK5HtDDtgbQs3f5PWAlp477nueSRW/uUfclVhpLtAnCkPkyedf7EUUUWBTvq5TNMdQq5DIO8szxVBFESyYQZD3OFCKifJPYUn@kmHGVC7GmrwomS4Gq@d7WOm7rEkKqJBPTIVu6Msb7/4/Kt6rlH9wPpZ6798L5u6EoiTP1M3ir6cYWGQyjUSVty7AN4T3ySTl0cyTzBS7GCLmYtLXh@oiJMTGep2CGnMdQdhs8GhMGkRjKhRKPNR0Ez1HO6V7ZNiPSJY65JUedEJYgflLNII6kMDA2uKQPNWV11WhnznhXocsAIkiOrQDK5Yz0VFmnbfQrVUGGV5xN4zkoeAKevQ4N/zJSW1h5rQ@tXHIZNbjR/Wyu5arSEdW7jIa/lClYqz3Kxu1sgEEreLKgbrr05H@Zx6Olrfa8DoXiD19HT0WS7/NWDd9SDWwyy2vL3nu1fLWi33/r1vjJksXycr/HAZsInlq6ODo73jk@2TL4@hFq5D1rbPj5iGvAapiE6Nd90eKW8EvOAw@xP4T2SbsEFUEZxKSfHzvRRU4FpW5WVujLGmqdh3RJ8X37di/jcDCJ4GvY0U9QxABQYRG2INC89VNDIRV2jdIyqzsf/ABhQhBo/wzeGlhCqZVQFZKiDrnqhiiwu7xd3ug7E7odyOtq25QRBjUXr1yJ8XcS4Krv9eyj0wfP9XLzeHcnu5Kcwt5YagkWsYZ3/74OmXL/amo4WdPHHd6kZBHGznzBlbGh@wh2oGSZ@MiIg7V6oykykCt4rOjGsvtoJLC4olmKPZ55GJQin/sjQhTMBMFZVoN4QUoiiUA5RvUBCZPXcPo@lYFsM@OgbuihcxYgL7cgQ6zLgmC8gJUgat4RMWA6EKdIVN74iYuODXST8u/mTCFodFwz566PM2t6Crinodn8F/rFcKTfkGGzHRnekNprI8/HqWcwYFDsOmKryPYsscEfIyz7sc5RcV@EKe2m8MWuKlEa44rw69dM8Y@KEwmGDP3cAqs7dDl3TihMwkki9Id7TBdW5T1XIt0qRrBwaCMHwO@y2Cd7B/XEXpjItmxN/jNDd0sKOCQFz1tdBaEXioJp6rE@A6aDnKXaEdNewqaUbUF9oQIynBZxe2b8OokCqhgzJODzgllkYUHFWokzYktt3zQSZpQ/cNEkqAXS0IJxodcuYnnVWHyQmgSS0SGTNMljCsX72pLRO60kscpr7mkZcpHEH2YzCTm0uqCpg7s51QX3oZFajTZGCZBd4QNyXXkjeihFkok0ntBv1eLOAcRcCnVvbjb/4OV/57GoD5R8I8yj0G268LWwfMvxH66DrY/llky4Ptx9z2KotVdlNB6iSfkbqXhcfCgTgfyTcKhowh1BxPBYqqHKv7q4Mj5puoLRgrtG@MYnWFbCYcpzC7D5RxQRWNwXkKk3qcwFHqXwGdAHEBkaCMg2INpWd5DQV1ZZazWcw4rvxqtDvcGvFNWaQ68@0QdUCDJJYtFoprehYyqV6EAEmh1RmecOUAU6kyMEbpwh5UX7dMtrm5yWTfNHpWtVjhBJJdNl6tyq@jjC5DWImPFuoM4kCUSQzwq4loyrKR1lMYFXuzpJ5ExtZ2Ob2BSKiQAYKk0NkJVeCAzOkKVAExOzAIJrFpHI6CgGs7bkw7cwhIBUAcNtdrPN0mJ6dWcWUi1kq1eDXILzHYMQYry/Motv6KnQanTkNorGZAfT@bQ78OmP/JHDXWnLJQxddNdcvKrLJkLA17dOy4uMizD7llSj6bX83qxVSMQmUBCvKL7f09gIQWDhzDtOw37sDf3tk7@Nbh0fENzXMUMjkbLMmStc30qapl6o3IkIzyPY3Ux/vZ42eP90NUxnM1mcXAEJMt@bPZnJfabE4XpP6SHxC@mTZ53EhIz90XMO13VffpVMtN6BPfbCzgDj@feCNVJXV1XW9s1k6dxI3k38/TjZ7QVpC4wHTqk2b05Gw2MYvRXSgneBeKr4V6L3RUeoFnogP3fKJCQzjEPHjwEApwAEnLhqEWMU/IwCGfAZroesrzy1h8Yn18logUXEc5ioU8Ca9twaY1UU0qdHJ2Db/bs1sSdOBtVNLLNWqFKqMiXVyaP@jZgZKShBpXECVQhaq4vGVUHmm0XURJYTMnWBl2m5rPEF5KgkYA8JJHQ7/LjtxBbG5r1wpNL0AaYbtDvnXAYt8a9iFchz4vLJpiBflEhciAqGSUVT6qhpYltHyO0qhJFdKro65PUXCt3y4oo5TWtUZt@wwYuJLKQEv/TAexKtJDgoUmzZ9OEngcx/DneMQzjtJPUvY6mgA36oZmO21rpKD2snID5FN0T16@vEim5Bs0QBpnd0IdlTOqZ8OGaASiRUzUts40to3oxpYZFb4bG6gBro87kasMUjwOvKdghP5J6fSNAVOGpBDaZxojq3KqOBk/8FJMrXG1Sg5Lp2lUDR/yAKkZg3bIRITDFJyHVLJVqB109Z02ft7ZA1bXNa0BZkokxZZxRm0HunKci0pJMEqCKGUCW8W6ZWXMEadejVMexEF/iZQ0MtSKPMebVPnS6oGLuKBSs9rDmHK7SQvkWN3YKIvamGY1GwzI4iaX17IAdg4LCaVUwK/QkwFYw4s78IYXXKEEtvDoC8txLEAQ0EzfgD7YGAKRealMeFtTZnLRA6WQ4Fl8IhRvQEanL4DYS171cAPLcrZCkzOVa@hTX59ip9oR3eo4@99ntWzlSlnuVcdZEHRSNWW5W9XTqyvp9LKzoiw72NU/fIhzOtfLIEk0NRgijSCQutxLVYCeQfKoLjuVZWNTWW5X8ysUA6wwSLuCCB/8rHa1bFxnlx9CT50BF483XmXZJ627OU3TryF/2EKWsxmgmStUUkpXNWHyy3Y6jXnQlpuYgQ/Z0@M08ezT4yxNH1WENJo964vmNsNVo5q4cVEVR6BwFhUNjD2PjF2cX2qGgVGPUbh4PcdvgezBE/4Clz4YLZ9aflz8l6d97s9YBL9LkkJEruOYqz0GBI4UQCJaM0YqBczkF79I6EUmK8tbxdXeRTpZyFXgpVcKrMA@Wz5V1fxyPcESj5YbhhE0YeCeXbk63S2dXTCrky@@rdsd7W2pepQ5bxwdff2h@eHVaJw6VZKJncP3sr4G4dfZBv3u@6yz/ILnnioDEytZKZFd0R@uZ7OvX78GoRefek2rhUG0xocPqbqabNSVdShVOOdRrzXW11cyxdJK5sWjZDOl5POpY9u2s@x04Lfb8Ku4XUaXpzUS/EmnFZVc4KXWudvWVn/UQcNo2zo7G@4ZY@5uJ4b42Q9E3GffffnyJRpe0sPeveDuLMEhMhGu3DQKCZbP5f/yT5euM1dHzc2//H4/ay3h5xA/P7p@huZjvfDZ0tJnjx@vrWUAW9x89N2j72xvb6/tZgpH9cLWmppb2vyLP19ayuc389mlhu/rjWT9/Gs5n1uTtb/8/WTz6Ojbvo8Vhs8q08GI7xL8dFYosHP2Dp7zDsN/Mr9rx8wGmludd9hBgrBcJWaTTBZWk8evklg77xK6rifG9NdMIN6XmF7bWv@vPzl8mwgStXz2pQffIPE2USwluBEMYFsNbReJWmITgxWvE@NstVoF4/p//XcQv/YtgIM@40141QohrOI4UVOrFOV9olYEg57PQ7r/9/e@R1X/qA6PvLael7ca8KzgsyklaiPwq9UO9lm@ll8R5KOXHuoPY/TmBF0QQE4Temnt8BG329ajw3whvwlGx8LLqKwgq@v5U06e8OiiahEVOr65A@uCGeqauYko6IQWhAuQx8sE0Q0QDtEONwsHIifu8HI23MtTw1hZT6/lHzmVl@KJDP9wzwu886@49Oj1bja7WQMZAJ9y@dFpU6Awy9ZLsus@kiOkVtjTiXHqGan4jAQCBZ5YiKjoEyJuym1i4zNYkzCfGm4Pn7/6P//qp3/1E/r7Kf3@k5QIN56p9YtGLXyAhuSaJ1@dCqvzjD3jj@PAv8Nq8gbQXiaTedR85oRe6At@iY1E9NRq@KJ/YSMTfWfchE8tslCISZT54ZhgPyFSE1LiQzbLsB2wi7A4j5bKS6VysZzPNmtRiSC/DhWHcs0Nz2KlfMbd4GHAIbe2luCP/uGJrPheIhfhTEFuPkusdp9nbv8gJeqJeqPBm3YtXkd3PS80JD2NzM3pPudCSqjAyNLpF0DaTJA4PKfpO58v05rWFGY0uPB1VdUdsYSU@Ad4ahJLXMHT@LBS/7ASplyvCcOm2qilRYbgozUfNdLq9XVde5WuVMQ/SIuVyIYPfBj8oCCNa1XdfAXA6tNgk2tusug@QugcOL215qtNAJ/erG9W3R36aURTauNVrb45DUJk7tGjNNbDIwBQW26wFIiiqrpUX1gGANhQGAxnoI6vN69r1/XN6@vNTfjfpPe1@ILr9eaNf/pMngVhJv4NpKrTerZ2mhWtvdYAu5atoYuWPQVDDb4QDrocKXGFBMnqDRWHV1W1rhcLDZIopMQKMMZsWV/Jr2YLo8@Ke3ngLj4Gz8tydgUN77GPBtFqQ0rgeGWDD1s2yOH1x2/@d/ydfvzm34AV8oaXnZJv6y3@PX2Hf28D/Dsx8e/FW/xjJ@/w70WAf89a@Hfk49/JW/zbbuHfSR//pESVMZAcl7dyvdxFTj/Xz8FgsxwI7t1cV29Dx8ZyFsuNc2OW67t6G0wW/OXAZOc6LHfGck7O0XXwBEPAcgGaOvA5g78OQPHgz87lEHjugkEqPewuSfk7fd83WepUqrPkawuEPU3XclrRbjZQkVQ92agksqenWS4Ds/xahZRQXV@zZnPv@W6zmcUWdvrMPZz8Hx7249Zb//uH7rNDt@/C/@Hh4bNT4JS19KO0@gieai29KT5biVpl67SsIkWGxJ/Ibm6d1lZVNBfTQM95dEt/4jOBCN/a0qmUvIT@9rJC3Xrl8qJyWSFDZOWGpggggnEDxKoIcQBcIN7pyyx135fwXBBcsqHxEjxDEzdkX16eohALw5boH9ARt/49/Nv/3/p/9iVT6o0UtIGr602FnhT@pVJX11fX4l1LKYqwKJvwhw5gxyhX1zU0UqArMNWVVCN1fc3d4K2kNjnAGqaxWaPIk4DAOxJRmpQufyl/v19Mmz@nSRDGYECviNXI09NRLpeqtMAlWpIw3tPCVqpCW36WW7gYCYNYPUUhCmuVir7Czfm1fKWyJizrpUqlJMzLirJx86nltvQiCB1ra6lUpZITYWG4WgmNAMLyDbOCbbySSGFmecNXcjgpSrf8JOWy/PChIi7F2hoMUg8f6hu59@8jp2azbXvNJrqvvn8vN2XcHVTdKIA9V3r/HnhOMuV6ynOXr0srqs4@y9cohQ3Xg1KtgzfTs/lJml3DN4LAU97Zg4yMm6t9OUWa@XM51ztN/vzH3//@abKK@0XIdU1HAJgKK2xuFtdqteIamIslKLi8zDcgKWfpDT11vZyVeXGZvJxMCC@9tJ4i1@sk@rPEJtuqQUP18WFX1wmqP7ZWSCmtsZW6ApfQTd/Y4I5sraiU0hvir7qUYrUVJv5wsLSaXltZX3mEo6XR/AdZa@XKqCaz2eR19coo4xTadcUU98DgOUjj4cPVDUBpKVc5lZrN3e2T7SZeiIsbBKBXZOhIfFrCxd@Bl6zTfGdho1HH4jVOk8ly5RFVvl4qsESyIsKpSWD5rLTB@X3C9yW7gyeiRwR25reSGDB9fRX6W@hupQFt1lrPsTaud3vM7XSWwBGqkLVwa4Jv9Xrh5TmXrtdrX9pta0lKHD3d3tk7yeQ3offO72/vZPLHXz5O6GgtTOzkvYr2F3vbu4dfQoSjp3vbx3ufH3y19@URuPvSG@@dYVmGNbSs5uVwePmWvbHtpg3Y6w1t23ZNDzLRtCxrAMHCp2JZzDJt33jzxvAG9DDOtD/@7Icff/Y/fPy9H3/8vR9@/L2f/vybn/4Qfn8Ivx/z74//7UYB3z//5p/9wcff/T1w/E/w@4/w@9Off/Nb3@M/sv8Z/P5zzO3PxC8Wjv8kgPXrP//mJ7//829@47fh9y/F77dv/n7zT@f/fvqDxT@M95M/uD3Mj/8d/P6IwwrD/vh3uRt@b4T/XR7uN37747/49/z/L8QfGn/v47/4M3wJyz/97b/4zx@//x/y@dJf/OuPP/zxxx/85OMPvv/xBz/6@IN/nP/4W/9az8Vff/Dxp3/83/7kj/7bn/xP9P@H9P6j@/x//O1/@tf/x1//X3/9J@L3p/D792D607/@D0C6f/vHP8P/n/zx3/7Hn@H///av/vaP/@e//fX/lQy/ww3/z7/8t/z9N9//4d/84J//zfe/WfD@4a3vb@7h/s0/gMv983kfOPcp16e6fPNL5edXwcYkFaAButmG5UG0fTy2WEXKsRzjL2iDP/0nH3/r14C0/wUEBNv/CDb45xbw@hFZ2NdfI9@L@7M0TbKo6a@/Rn8xyP0abIkazY1hD1DKl9IrIO2ubGzE5swiMD@CGO@zIKPnHr0HEF9TfP6wr8NgkLf/hYJBOCaCheGmM0lhcAcqd//5N//898kjiovOvzYFMhc6x0MvY/D3ITp@hO1@Utx46B8h6/j4s@99/P1//PFnv/PxZ7@OfYW6tpHZzkCPf/sMNAQs3CMcBizeJxwE1HF0yZbYkpQHw9ImzptKevr1a8j9EphgILYiFVbBJuk1MutohohpsPGZs1Ea3/AvrW0wtIDLiFzhy9Lg9TjNqtVqWhpVwY@CghXjjFitBE4jnNmoAlyMxONkmiUY47DRY4ICMavpF6y5Uh3xiGl0qBEEpCsJnV7Iel5Ol6q7kGB1tMsQFgJPS6/h@7paK1VHNQT3gbIAMNKPIUkIVcXcjWofwF4lmBBeGu1@gKyUqul0rQQuVSxkmlLLNClNvUCFo7KnGZUb3RnDnaBbjxj7TNZLMp/RAVQyERrf6UloDAjBwf80vSKKQ/@hkX4rGB/qaUT44W7cfwudKb4IAHBVFTcQwk9VMTePwHvEQaUpWfikOQTAXJrEqhAkOJAAk5bSVL9pskD6kIdPfgDkZk3iBVpeXpbQKq/KzUMYXMIozjsv@4Hh4RInSZhlJhc3ZHTG/VhhAXHb3vIRjUVXdlfgrcP/3hLtsaYyVVak5STOcySZSPWzNP89erTCPgMc0HfiJjE1vequuQle3M10Ws5DwjUXbCtU1DQBwnkI@k9LrxISSxANQKPJ8Dd8tCq5Mximi/ySw6uqhDnLr@pox1nP4XCIMTQto2Uy4qvRlxw0YdDIV3y1ZZIk@bHJHp6/COcbNiQ@VGJ6cY2O39BdgymWkhKmhSIak575Z4/dEQxRMrKc0Yu4TpYSEz0n5Ty2YmmvnIP3d9xyufpBX1uX4Ev2Id55KG7fA3rqWp6lbW4iXdSuVJqOQiPItkWpVhO7BZgu1Y73TiD4ySHT8zmNwfDmam09v1ZYK@RXi8XCel5fK26sFQulVeC4xVwhn9c31tY2Shvr1/N40yPgX5nySquwWftHN57/7h/Ne@a74iPVvmYjDWf91Wup1qvyDazLuIlAPs3JFZolI5Qu13MZ/MuvrsIbspzRC@uNpaXelYoYOKVdk1e4TQNyLV2puI7wAB4mPZDYA3CCB9LAZVQmNr4cHFbEJge8wplvdJD1AlA6VMkpkDoHJ/3/z9/3k2BXV1exn5RY@u53A1arwehPPdiXEsD4uizcKKHaba2r0e3M7aFnke8ZY7sHXx0cHxw@13YPjmE09h1o1jlNSlxfX3eiRTyyWhL2Nm2Md22SSwvM1yNDGsSfypRtIOXzan5VXdVVfRX/7zDk8f/@4fPwn8c3xFrNS5tcjVANrxl1jXY1uoqbKamrdrXtmnQUq9Kp1hsaHsCutLWW2x5rfjCGwXXb9gc9Y1xNtnqueZ4MPW28nwwPSVazRlZrNgGFgQsjbhqjb@XXC@WlrJfVcJu60mGprXxxHVxOndAJXAro8mraaaPc1sIcPYMWAvHy5XyxcL0ptAzWoDyYrxrm4kpkruy4jnWNW5PLRgc455XJt/SU5XyhJFfqlYl9vShXGteP@lbbNthpDk/CXc2NWCzK12E4SBrH6zijwpQ@3imEe97LudNcakHkHESGLFNOpU2huqhGmzTqwAIbeLNqvbEZKjWqSR8@fBjRvqjygROIDVL5tRK6MwknCB6CoPVQ58ZCcWLMofEEFVA9h7oDxu2wp3jOIXDZicv30z@2zAUhdroGXTS747m@/yuEeWw459xr1@aKbyKvJwbq0/f7dtBdEOLLQR8Pz1vePxiEvX4LMog0xQM8hpfXc915AdbZl0cLSvksUlyHe6lIcx0Ef3Hw@ZOT2Pdkb3vniVRkjw@f7858CiJQgT3d2z@JrOvcN4xaiEB8Z@/p01mr@ICUUKGprCVWWMe91KEFenkjMGS5zkaNSgLwElyDUF2qtJ3hlv7woX70FE8rFNkaiOGr67lyeTnLoCFUrqFg1cfn5QHuzfatwYpf2xsdedjC/I01KDAbsi@hCi4rQA@JEjRSWb6Gtrm/vYNNMZusJj@om20@QpCe4U7uDZ0fS7R9iU4H442meHtxIKGCnLZ76dCJy1ZvaLHhgC10hA86odGzz7oBCy7dMIDUMgwGv099IL4Vf4LbHQKeBrnd8OnNCY4bh@wOy0kaiW/5jVKhtLGaL2VKG6W1gl4sFDJ6PqOvl9Y3QOTI6SW9WCps6JnS2sbqGohI4FvYWJcSICrYnWwW5FJdluFbBrCOibdybeL1Zq7WrUkJPt/M3ilGiiWMyD5ksgVxZLwO1g/osMqKXZXza3iSDORUgGgwkyX293dy@/uy/BgtuBq2k5PlNloKpVxu/bEsW@SzA2JcXpZdHqeEx/zlgFtyucc7sjzkAFC9nix30bJXxMGzLNto2dne38d0OmjJY3wIds59uKUXWtYhmIOW1VUafcvy2wgchNvmCa1RTvfQgmmizz732QE/Wf48zE8uBxBe8HAcwpOwrNvbsnzALdvb6LNDBS/wrH6Blm16ZNkDCxChLJ@B4Qy7BFlugRFJUZZNMJljA9zwBjTUsOZgOxxzBCGKZHlEoQ3zXIYxonDHZJ48eWJ0g7Z1xp@xx7/QxA7Axx4N9/Zbn3/eOjtreePtvc9foM/OzhOjMx56rbOWiNZqwuNCHPA5749nH8jjQbNp9Ob6fAE@zoxPc9y0MG9N4y3kSTxnmEi/uQM@O@Azb7qeQ4OnD0Fb@Dzuw/ex0SKf8CEf@o5aLbmChIqaEHByHdvMuQO8INM3TM@toH1UXWJJJZkZ14u5RoXcWV9hqSvgXejfUehSbRxXgZB9Na6PqrlGdVRdz4sTb4p8OsoXbDmz1N/SN0BAMbb0/Fp6VMZLGNxOkiVVfUvRH668U56DLLK6VpZPt7ZUua43tvJ6qVxcf7UylOVUGd9bq@vldzDUSsJ4Cl@p@npjC6SeSZT19bSRzZfX13EYVrkGjATQK7WGgdVsKsqlZZynUphj7OtBEqPisjEV1a50lFFmVOUZY2OIP6rqFa7yh@VuAGujtrkhXmDLQZ4piIHRVq6MixyKrG@UZMhCNqukUsiYkJXA9/XLcCU2@sQMU0b@aKys8vuv9VIxpeERqqbbadIdoOx1PORkG4P0Ek89ksaDcHMyTQD4ZekEh5nYI5CEZbeAy3CFVSNpxJVKMT4nqa9vSFJNDK2O@KWEFWH9/MmOBqMtYUP9ddo@Sriup@0g25vy4brVQqcT6Oq0JxZuOTZDtx2ui0DbG8GoGsXk0CPUQ6QJhTHayZPKldrEhZFvn5yfnHytXsfBHsMwk2cEz2xVSDsQaj9AbX92mxnVGpgMlCcpl4CC1CWho1mrVZvVvtUfBGMocxjvC0bK8CaADnxemOgsGUW/wvOVwqNZzV1Pwj8f9tljHogOYYbRmtXHgN9cxUHluRZal9koMZJqbVQF@Lj6@GpYRpn0umJVLc9zPTmBJ1e3nOrQ8Y2OdWR5eGjy4HCZdZiFxxPN7uvTPQy5g8L1tVrzmDOVD8VQa63UtFPMiqhTvh1h5Iq2/eNa3jWMUZRXqcpbsHnLTGlrj1Nba5W28pg1U@CSe9153WF5Vlyr0H0zCkICjkCYQ4wYqWrtCwDM4Z6Xy5ARQRLnABMTWoYasdvkY6QG9nXlrFrH0O/xtanKckNV6@8bUq0i1YDBVMYJo@oPW/wi6VxLz@eKlRG46etrlS5rVVuvRhWvOoCxJav0oNrFLAQ/y2DgvnZAEsB59175@GvfY6lNtVDljhUC9r4HwkRTa1ZHkxpardbza8VMvriGkxbFVfjpmfxqHrfqZvK5jUxeB5kCZA2ID791sK/BD8KAyJHXcWpD6SkyY3ImN8ppeka39IySe223X6cy5zi3BGIhIS2VCdw9BygHHJCAgGzJCl8jlc6v9JS2y4xNlWgYmF6FCmpkumxgZ7oI5oVl9HjwlMpWV5TesoJhlk@Gg716o1zeGw2@jV6K@narmF7Ppd@lUhVliaWqvvWWsIz8kbAwWAKKFjM2zB/267klKDe0QfUaajtY1tfz5fpwua7qUMDc@7NNuSY3oLqumQR/8cViELsq4BbyQS6oTUStidsAZeyeBVWrb@QrIog0EIxZkZVTOTx6oyST6/lkMpWs4ETmErgLxk4sOAm9QvKhviWDqCeX5Y28DDx9ws9vZIFP9RV1KXEtoQjO1jakxJV0fXW9Gd@K@AUbj420GlofMnaWXpZYljbzaM0EWyKTqtVoxnm7un32YjvcBbu9IyXKtGV2sqGRnQrlCUzNLn3qFqL0Zu0V/57i9jlIViK1UnXWoB0Blk2adr/Cs2RbLAnlMrx@PZ9fbdTz69CnAyMOg@bzUHT/SuII51vOspvpGsueSrJMLIhvUCgVUrwU7EOCGj3buQpnOMp04wFTjDJv5PVG6sNzu3dVWlX5UFxhiQ8sndVoK2Yz@yEBneR1gu/gzs/u4IashDtyv3idL0BtOW7oAEPxALg@9LSFgkwzsq/Z4Hjj1fqr0qtnXx5@ebjPHuXKpXJp7pLM6aNMpqwnN3FQ937JxSHcB@db32YVVkkMkqtryQVLOafVxKi6FmKC6bWaqm/m2RbQNytDv9DRi2rufY0Ta408innw@fhrv7022iyBPQ@idRmQXUjnazV9hY5FpBKDj9/8Gzybe7X31fZTlkRNKX/357@fX/@7P/9XtBckeV1Bt/zqegJColEvrieurgZXV9fwcL9CopEQW2bW1lNg4Rt19EQtmxB7S9b1VMJXRSh9vZDw3wvdSUo@VwK/nUNuk4uA1cTeC7uQ1x9tYu3oUe2w6G/T8jcSUqL07PV7xsBi1tpnZ3aeTNnsLPLKMFqF/@UPOL39QV1ir6s1tpzFqfsNDB1OGK7UarUVXF5jyVoaD6LnSUlFrX5daaQZTefhiG/FoT/LX8G/yP7KWvF9sIfe1sobf2UqH5sWK9Sgxley2exp6uOv/VY@X/y7P//N9833za@Bn29sbBT1fOIXkKVbDoqGIz6aN8Ijn2iIRopswfW6milLCbxzucN4@HDciCNFVJPAlUyhTbpwbaFJqAn4NEBMVyjYCh53y5DATmfjUxVJiqRaEsi9MzNDMNgKahSHRihdSQ/QC/pCVgX2Jz2YgAKHPmqnMpt@b@gNSLZUKJ7eyLCHEAVSeID6TJbomJ7goapeYdmVm1F5lrlqI5JeWN/yfVRpBjxeegBRngJF0/1mbGDgUU8MaTvAtDUMQvkkj3Yd0m5A2j0eoUmuCpWeB8gwnjseyQGBXXqA59ZIoocuntmbEKDCUtIDQACUQRGA7QbbZKspdmWn05WJBrRr3PWI6i@M8CCZhNEQWhtPT4aRKxjO5lpOhh5q/mKihk0r7hgC4TD4KlwVxhoYnWwoItFZ0XuDAlikM0ChorGHDye5qlbtdopRiRA@KoBDrW0TdVU3EgBg4UDts3ZZzjAnncbKfjBNdoDxNGUXqE4lwyRQB0/0ofVakuD/3kSLFDlTVeRRwQKI@uKtwgSUQWREO69DE1XY6fn1FIsyb0LeTcoUacKJRp@no880Ukhl8ixeS79IhNp3gb@cxMdIgm5nTxIy6OGGqBcV1SRwZiDOCPJrnJBPHQRh7CgWFMXuUeiO7cFog9YOQ506yqqewmidyIXyQaw7v8ZwI2IhhR@KhaFR84qBWkxEOks0NU7q3/yB65DaEzpCjts1SRmdL3ElLzzbQ@fSIAVmPBXa3RjLEdcKh5RPSsscrpnN53FxnZLr7Re4yTDrTCP9PvkNpnBNgziH6UTgUhSJMgxjTANx3OpZfcjSsWUxVL3hl7PZM5BOhi3StfHMBrrq7tvQfTh@Vlwsl720z@3sCar@VN0OiLzibGcCBRo7UnslFFqQ1rqefW7xoa8ydTjXZ/liBkTKDGB28gPEllEEwAO4OfDO8FDwW4fPOjeWMrG4S8o4dfO7qi8pTazR91yBlIeXx10YTgy/9LyXxIDVH/vhyXs6Cgp2LWK50DL58bsknr@LzoVKQkVAlY6vazjhPlBALgsPjKIRpFjrAkKouoR9DDBNMzzJiq0YSvuAOgBqe9CyUDVN4JXxiHcVlbYpJjQ9weAd9hlbzUukwo@UHggdBQADq746DR38ICqWww/aUDEan7UAvgKts98GvwRqauLkh/FD6kYzqWmakDdbEuCw06G0qow3i9BSiFmwdXCle1D0JfAsQg7n5GRJkdMANi2nZA46ij8bnVO7RLykzG5CyjCEIFANUFBUeGz4XO@30CtzeXmpkWqjoWdrlo@6nn28FDM7OLNBgHWzgdUfiBt7bLy4TVxKOTGpXMM7Xp@6NaJbSzcejvlXkjp42Prt0PYsJdnxk9gHXqD24rM@6Y1AjQ4@0c2@TRrPTYVWXH1BZvlG5iokszKSmVpKXiMQxhDMKDPOmBkAlmmZ55nOZbsiPPh93wAcKssKHVHroBda@n5osgedKIQb0Mbp0N7qnZtuz0XRQ@aTs5OkeQnDkOPQKuwDewSRHOuSbXueMVbIP4WhkU6VMUk3bAy9O/mAEXoTdsWVc9mj@rgxFX0URYe@K1qm9VBrhHR1O1CuEw39R9x/BP4j7j@aJBomWx81uOSFTtdYHCRuVAIVhkQw4zDMNVfpNvEhyCAiM52DwJDjKbdr@JlVih3im9ugHqshYQBNkCZFBVU41k8bjm9drjTS2TOgaZkQATUOoOsNwullOzIj9nsXvYHrTzk5qCMJOh@Rb3Qyu4IaOK1gGaMKIsLg@LJRlc5ZX@PzM7zfFwUGCChugSdKANuBYqcqkRJb8gTCqcsTHPOM1UVmGiRkCS/hBlIRRz1HbBxQIwYI3aMiQTbBh4UtR@jvF0zgpYeXKIdhVdLHT9p4k40kYHKmqXCWUqFKiuVKVcNsAtpRKq3OFiX0h6qoz3jFinkt6j@e/aVPzn4H2sX83BPB8n6hIsWbijVCzaOWaC6EVVarxuoVcpBdMXqWBx3UHhdDRacMyaxkw9EETweLwDXmKrHKN1O8fuhMiuzI5YgUxtUqFHFc5c2St4sQpRzhUTRfRBuHhCDicwYCMHJzo1ki2igebVStcsbBRguiXcYyOaJMjngUHnq0IJMNEQ0GSZFOVqyeBqriA4FKBng67y1R7azMfOMCdQuzN6g6BwZPYZoTnkNUIGgIJWmkM7MxN/V6LNMxpjUDAAnxBoA2vzKoLM0yPF2NbBGP4qgMeRS3CTLgvAIIjFhwhatHUyIio6EuyPVymvoBaLtyui7JOu4ho78c/8mZ0DH86Tcdc9Mh9WnHXGbm7x/EsYGYjTXQmJCh59aQIeOAZZu0xYBYcukyZY7wDO7Z8LrpbKvntrJ9A/dm4JX00SXUqXA8QPogHw3cwAjctbUyHwTZRF9fiuAsdmkHHwPYZ44LQ424@kWbq4t0kqgV03TPHNu3MnjtNRfBLdpBwC9CkeJyrzC6viSJ6UM@LEXQnIBQdG028aKzZlPxrV4nVY50m6JVQzpMJiUcz4IpFh/4kAB6OFDc1hvLDFJ3w0TdpCLaiW2eK4cD4ZmERLYZMCsT5Hnw7YKownx3MhIkpYEoGrcChW5l6bp99wzEO1QIirFnwB9MYGOGjMGA8pJhBg5RyzENrtQcFDNjpETULz45KvsirxipKH5@GsAUMjLMm8UxYtabk1xzYXI8Wpje8afn9zie3@Pb80uj6tk886F2lXt@WtKrygQCBJxkY/XubGSE/u0b2ZnKSuSMAhSPcO8stmnvUxtzug1Bt0VwrQP0kYlsPmkFEhn/ahH@b6/AMPrefavPwHsfj8fAb/q4xU6hi5D8cGlRgeAHKeQ9N5OLSHv3nmlBWLx7Yx9lBZBXiXE5qHIKGuYAhtF@pIIkBHwHzePWpht0T/udqtxzTp68iww7zy@uot1m2@oZY6utiJCZGNywxC9gZEb86n4FR0ZHTM/lgzoFOqlUXF81Ip0HKi8gGSNzEdNWfiMMD2JH1EMz35TDg8X4Q/8brBmn7Kp89hkE/mQyQYrt6R6CwXgw5qo6e6TxN@SjvP/hNYknc@9GCOBB7IrITJJN3cY@XyhRke7RI0Rhtekik1KusNty@4ObdfhpKLq7pFC5sUjVsJanlIkvqnH7thqPUUVIk3zp534keRfR3ZvmYqTGgU1Y2M6ndSE3IONuCNNU4hC5y6015jo3eAK60bybs6BXac5hqFFM4nSBTeNqki9SEg6BD@CLE0hfwRcBnllBkxNUWDacoxIXyzHy6RuDmNQiXEAaBygxLIZXRlA2YqGk0AzBr66jNM2FaZo30jSn0oxawHSSsUCSOZWkqAWsntuqoGd1ggXcGb1wkAyf29g2PI5reDgtcZW0k2U7w5IXyTIw5KSVLO8pwJST7WR5lwx@snxMhvNk@QswTNpW8n2yHDYLDOCBlQyP0F2wcLSbyfKOkrqWArzVI0xXS5ajOoUwW9xKGAFUYLlBasQlM8cVxQw8Czo2EiozDCnGz@A4iSZcMvTLwT9X38@vmQFPnLNcocAszfSpTiPWY/B0oNsIFbvOacll0ZvvHe7TbqLJ/Qjgn4bBXDwOgQcxPJGcZkY8Y@hLKxTwhQwi3yzPzxHTpy/RuEd2ROpAoVTJ0@kT9jSSB9oK@dchcCM1fTeDiB/W1zQIXoH3yydGXpTPG9kJk6Mc4Rprak62EKmvk7cUCut65uIRXvvxGqK56@lAeC1qGITXEoGN8XSQ4WixDRMbuINpIiFf3CNox@PQ7BtvlEi9M9GIK4iWucCbnEXJkDHEG3/qtuLE4mHWplgQetZzDd7Kon6BeDF6TXhdTFLljQ@yEOM50MIt89xCst0VRgrH2U2G@opF3VAYlydJnGuaTUJkDVWMDI2Apx4NXvdQ8cinDV/DmCOcVFEQQCxmlArnr@4nyO8ul99DgTpEwkwC8wTr@V3pTfH61l52Jue9SbI3KxA9M2w3NVc4ilKYoBxGBzHJ/DZauyHi4xYOLuTzRCPoM9J@iLZoTHAH3mbHFhwWSgnexbTjeR4cz/OLEXVTIuldaKHQomFKAg4veJTTSdFuzysv@LwqRh@ayDZ6n1zB3nQFxysP4VEBvBmU81aOpz5xbWvStklrLrogS9XLjDNyWv6MqnniCOyelmKjZVhwOGy@2D18/vQ70Omur6@nRB89nuQPWy1Oqkb9OIdMO5mj/mDOsCWfQa3xuHhN1/jiFcNLp458g5dwZg3CAN6WE5KfaOMpwcti/Hym7UI8HjaGUQHrfNIMjCmuhKKOgV22LfAaAEKsQFkxBJBQvAV8Z2i0lsI5WaAOvHiv2aTuq9nEzUjNpujFsGrCFe7ULxJL2aHv0X2tXKf1pSTR8W22e8hePtk@YSdP9tj@lztfsO8cfslebj8/wePOR18@fnqww@C39/x4j01mFPDBez5wQAl43bVMq98Clp3P5dYYQd5xB2POd5SdFHc/NvrsiWtauB616Rv9R11u0RwrqPFYezAcHeMcpk1XyfTtIOB35JkAjoSbNp16wyMBDMK2YEzbxzFv323bHRvCSjj2HdiWHx7KYj0bahD4bXjgMsOFJLxzhLYC0X1zdFUg3jUH4XGRBsAY/uRuQ9vnEay2xgTioueTMXiy9@LZMdt@vst2Dp/vHpwcHD4/ZvuHL8B69J2D558DPg@OT14cPP4SvSjgs8Pdg/2DnW1y4BnIaQwPtNPlgbdlQcPghBXzHJe46dbmyBafdYZgIMGzS4PO//ksOXSQ@9hGz35ntZMVCW8j4mcOaU2ARXcBMustLmWGa760n0D@0qf7dJZzbJNSg8ZSg/ZWEc0Vuj3UbI4LD/0xw3uVrAodLlfIPLmviTbltG2LyTu45wTnvvkZdGrLIWhIaAlgI6hwA0qV0TUByWRmk0DWIDWz56KSNZ4a3xQoLBj1Ubh1pCIRxsTeFwSK5wQOHJwP0iuRA9A9OORFsoHHA7DVyIEHYGvcAUXRA9wLwgoixDA4HCJ7ZkXu8KY/2Kf1X7YeOTw2aBRbEnni9UZVarDJHfB2f9Cjix74LA/d32T4pm1TFJ/C40UJvV54iWLLApIHniiuvMK9ahBSBmbTwaUGsY3NGVLDBl@gBtz3Y3QCnynVlMZOcLOP5dj8Bo2znuHwLU2TrThEe6yESkiqYkO3HV1NQScvBi4RIF4XM52PKN6ukAqt@8aDmI9vpGiIPY90vVG4peyuDDy@kYFfBgwAUqdGOib1VHT8E8G4HUHKiu8CReK87Yd4eCDn9tC0piKEV1y@sd@9SwkkZ6bGSeG@Q8odVBHeBprha5Yd14M2Tmy1j@dYkAuaXXcQ2LwOlekSTC4og9DYsUFqr6u1qdToUtKZFB3XiSXaAipekGoLiPI@qRLF80XyiH2FbT26IY320WF2jBZeVDxZO8vgItKlhdMvIAjz2x2xt6HbeoX8KU14xwe6cbNUre0@PlU/vM7g/Q6cLfA7zcJNhPyGzj6mBc2D1vloA6KHcpdoaeElIf6whbHFnjrBLbGVh8BgHNi1YVz3qFmJ/Pj24ZvueEBl1p0c37@v8lgqcibOkYd@V5lwtwyrh0lmKE6Dib0eMd4JmQVer4QuGYIZ8etHeBYFa6ECGHGQj9DdutOXcwgWEpauNewAZxHXb4nqjuCnWI22ToSCJD1KvD6yr5TH1XQtlZ3sHGExdCohi86EkPF2rsn@E@qvboDbvR0c8O/7gyvdmjvePXwStN1boX1S3tT0Yli8W4rBuj/YD7eA5Z3bLwUWyp5ZDJh3kjehRZQeEWdmORHtjr09xdc36o7aHoDBvhdnUCKgsdSGDi1Rh5pQFR4hFQczEYiOT3b3XrxgMh@fQFzgezhkaAs2iLCX@N0lfPes7RCz0yKhKRosR8JT6DK1dS18bmvMc5G3gFUIGSQj8BExi@mbQonriZ6FRAjaTU8MMcTcdO6uQh7k1wXga1R9C8wrMRHDogJKc4uZ4J2P7cc3dQu8ZbhsHN@TTzumed@Nd3554zig@OYf4wxPisyvv5dcPi6H6XABy3o7pAK3QZLGa281dgwJDyCgpk3X4C3VElYpbprnAnYixB3u8MpNS9i/OkERIXEhnMvCMbYuhGORNS4fL4diDu08xG7AwC2dwpPvUAaPkMWTy2a8QlOTTk@Z7oJAyMTbqB7FqQKiN64r0QW2yqSfrEYCebytLVNu6mEuGzg7K2BXFgf6DPc2F2fZw2xSwG1vTUr9@0mK9xJTKYU4n1uY0BMgFwuF1btgz5YijK7@qrB5HzLLP4P@AMb3E5D@2KfpfaDcg@eZ0H9CALegjm@VDxvMTEQQdeb0KVNlp84onj/IC58XgsygWmGzi3dvTaeaYqOZvM2HznukOHQKcqMMsSYcFZS3mhvYv749OWTId6a39Onp8caGgXCP4PUvosN1MT0sMSc8bzrtZnmeQ8H4saS@i8fH6DTSrWfm6NAc39DKC4OetMwWL0BHHDLi22oz4RQDJUKzihre1YeTepXZWT1Vr8RLuH/wdI@tkOq6ztQUpOzJqRjLWbKd2zJArJemI7DXoKN4n/ll@EEeMiFIQBMdylMIN6k780YYAWG5Tpc2iG2fgqXqs5Xe8U3DQaUgGZmuuX4IEWnyde9wPzVvQj1XmYoPmfMHjgKxMrKqyRQV3HAeFyFNg@C1ie6xfkrCWwvEBslbbvY1snopV9yQqHROJsj06xuNzIpZlRn0uYbT94feZfv8zO1edFiPDd60Rub43VvGCmtsFVVOPuQaM/ViFU@5Kgw1jpTYRo4IVmRwi3SSnsqMaaRpEdeT2WT4XVliKTLQWLmMJyBmqJSt9EMqxJNyQbVfLzaqTjVX6dedRgXP6gXpapDW0wo6PITOE1gLX5CvBw3sSn8Rn221nAvmDVtjGCVFZz8Ynf3A/h1nuMSebZovp23G0gPcrIZnSDTHulSiW8uRMiWUf6QHdIhHx2PjNF2Msy1tG3IA2M@AsOqP6D1OSQ9y2nAQuOQjElKRhNh7@730IDx1lKMJAwhStxthdjYJziSMgus@3HXMd0OrOpfGdDzqmIqBqGNM4nbyqSzjEUDMqDh6VW9IvmYZZhczgfdTvqdobHOTX1x/Dd40SYc7NQyPDj7kGmjE9Q34DGgxAZMgwdyn4xsSFB/tOhq4C01BBXTehTa6SyQIog9u42ZXdByJ4m8CAjjiH3CRShMzmEKwAjmRH/WjuQPURzc9rsdVBDwFySvlARYWYfP0qhPgtOObcITJCjSB@4NLRCfHFTyiBKpOthvFiMKneHBCCS1DC5uPuKQqJa8afnqTaEosmhpGCwPHUPHgTmzgRBaMfp5Z0HzGbMfq9SDTHBcPJuhAIx3HFemno/T9OqbZiDLP/dUb/uqUv8b9eaYmoTTovyeByvFAcuJqEu6ayZNgmRtpVRnJJhrUtKmBxDEJW7ktrK8FbtOeBK5FVcmpMvLYnPJQYz6v5tQ@91maihMReORf5/6CvvOi5qNcToV9NJ0@fiVRQRbtjRVbSWaoVHPs3hbvnCIfJDMZsMkYj471TWTHG6U4MinYCQhoOI1PzbZWnUBJ6yHHoTYj1zYfyZoQJraU2WzwQ4c3GtacNhLDEqWZJsSN6HwhpEPeSzEQBBMJjYUttxZGHovI4xhYDLUUJssPLd5o4FC02SZexWOM7/EVNvbpzIXhEvM9H/Ccj3jh@WHkaQQR012S56NpmpvgsQ/uKAp1Sy8ySXs8C3E@k3gem@SN0rT4kekOznIvRXwizihCTnED75GPwPQkgB6S76IqRM9r6RfZFelzA0ToQc8asW0cRRh0mkqaOo@OKlp9VJxEKlz84WDQw0VFEuwu6cSzUOORL@BqygRibBlNkw5w4w4Pn0GTOD8OkTR2iJAvcf/HxMMfnuGt2bhug/qSgLXihIodaNK2M@bzFdBmVvP8VLjFhj5fFIXB/Fk8E7zmeOtBTPsDw7Q0CWQxH6QciRe1w9u3mC7HYyGougu6tLIkfXtom@c7n@Ny7bqeW9VjKLsQq705bXVtclAKkBR65HMgrhb0NUmKLf2afOlXRYAZ9hQ7@q@ANq0LvJtZ2oYegwL6IJz6lndhtTVJemFFa7wIF0kZFx7x2LQ79Ew@dwOyFd7pjKd9/Qxf7QIKwy/2z3w12KSlsIyEa1KTxWSo6gu7jQgMD5R0XFz8pfUIPNXP8YGR@lYASFlJseks0dKyyAvJLn2cZwJsoFqS2NJDhAbHDWwTaoYmqqQegOKrHJPE@A30sZxAembPwEO@2rwM4OmXCQbCDIQrRbflQRJr4p@UByYKFi6hG2HNZIH7udRWoLlbng3cd4JgqhWKFss7VPDJk4Njdny4f/Jy@8UeA/PRi8OvDnb3dtnj79ASNq6Dk85Y9uTwKXCXaLGcL4ofgoO8fQwxZfKQtp9/h@19ffRi7/iY/b/tPdt2GkmSz@Yr0oUtqiTu1tUIdSMJtemVLY8udnslDSqgQHQjYChkgd3ac3Yf9gf2A/ZT9mE/ZT5kN26ZlYWQpb5Md8@c6XPaKqryEhkZGRkRGRF5cKhqr9/u16A1aP6w8ua4Vj1Kq9qbnf2TXTpchxbUm4NjtV97XTuGYscHaepVV0tE9dTBnnpdPdx5BT8r27X92vEH6nGvdvwGO8ND@4p6Wzk8ru2c7FcO1duTw7cHR1WFA0vs1o529iu119XdLPQPfarqu@qbY3X0qrK/PzPQg/dvqoeKfACsUW5XAcrKNqiq2BONc7d2WN05xgFFTzuAPABwP62O3lZ3avhQ/a4Kw6kcfkhLo0fVP51AIfiodiuvK9/A4BLuA1iBedk5Oay@RqABE0cn20fHteOT46r65uBgl3B9VD18V9upHpVUYv/giBB2clRNK7yZirqGNgBb8B2et0@OaoS32ptj2DNO3qI7gweT/B4QA1BWoOouIRi9HHC0gKSDww/YKuKBJiCt3r@qwvtDxClhq4JYQIeJnWO7GHQISDy2h6neVL/Zr31TfbNTxc8H2Mz72lHVgwmrHWGBGvpbfADSgU5PaNQ4TwAXPwKxJjTlpmk6VW1PVXbf1RByKQ0UcFQTaiG07bwSnMNaziUsY0l3gLYB/8o2oLTvvvoYYKLHu5aX@bYYk@Bo52C3Cjuy5JNyog8nsOusz2Q@sr/BTmM@ws9YhplW0Lju1Lv99gBjRU01NnBchZ00Xs7hgXquzhJfuJ9F7ChUIZms199V6qDoHtXrXvoxNWNgPFRDrNxfKuXJGDF1PGreaOB5@ZLxvhlD1NaCnGOSHx6eL2BJxv4Ce7b5V4GncrlWINUwCB8b1iaikE9FLvGkBFgjxTLitRRRl2SBoN9dIQeq6Orms806mkHR8ZEKDUL4p/9j9IM3B@sFcGc2a@VyqMQSGN1Pge6GO6HUBvSPZBbotqnLbBgEP3TcvN0d6vzZzmDQcj1P16GyY9ADO673QPVG0JmpnpmtT8DSqbJknA@13k0ijDleFpQpmZfsiEbm4j/1Mf3xNDScuwGNotQV2aLFOOkucHV0OEorSVGB0RM0ySjzva58V3uP2ly@uFyaef/KvOe1he6AmKoWNrxTqndOf16dcwFYYJRTA1DSlUwXuZxVR7uTmMI3UPASC1FKftqrLwPa1wElIMhe@z27T9yNR92JDT3w4W8OK6@3T/b2gHUitMvrK2urpYTJkvVdmv9@wH4ogSolCRvCPg5yGn2yVskOCD60Uqys2xH5EwHnclgQ85rrSaOXmK/BuGXEHZWQkeFwQ7yjpY8eeE6AeHAUJdJ4mtD0OndlCgG4saF6OJorf0Iivg@yEtGA@Kr0pjRrE/wH2zbLXy9xMyAhICExSlsLlAvaBfE9Z097gpJyQ3l2sEjW0XTMWdcMDsjURe6xGDxLv4S2rVkM2VMR1ytNO9UEIJ7OQqG020SfV/Zbyhcihl5K9gVvvhN6g8cPko@OstP54bgyPgI07pmaaI@OjM4y6FNp@XyrDFO0sGB62lRozfcEKFp7YjY2CT6s1UCgnKPPYFnNNFwy@UBmuyQH169TnvrMlIpJOLCdklCs/AbKnTccaaWk84DIb51dQnFbJlkJY@3G9JHQRT6YfBQanTE0/SJ8UPu/I07mtL8JGie0HmHLytn3KExSq4wrUF8JKd0bfaBgnWJE2LRffYiaubUn5tIMTE5pJhw@AyiQ2ZnqFx8oS2HbnYMAJHI0bNjr13icXfqgOn3teFIdz0P6zauhq2Sv0FvFnXYzq@dpErvS@gwFf3jKY1uT1eE@VFVfs@LWoFUPKtOMKq@ehw435@k8HrlFMoCYBU9UeslOqbOUlZdVpvmApEyyNpyWyXwEYuntvadzi8rKaBnj/XLCpREFTW8hPHfHSWnOB4q9b@MJEjmt@jElrcNM26gm4@YjGeYa5GfZC7Cd5y0yhuC9suMb3CB63Dpl1otaU@5z8gPBTiKnwigtILJbLwuopW31xkBPlkmkUAP9SZ/z1Qds1dIlspy/QyC0o@Gz6rU/BZB7jxs2k1hu8WiQRtdE7IzNElIf79BtDgYjEB19HDfAmO5Ovax6L0aHoB9ejyTdIOxn3ZFYJLTQD92g2MTaO20znBqdQAu7YwxGaGWJPmhIVwE6gHL2kUlmVblAvJpGt7TRsTtZKih3M/qyCTihLKKExE21qn78kUsxQiXDZ0AY7IZGuSCXTOoHzx3M8rsZjH7AvR9FoH4raJlEolaTZAvkSar1KSVjc8xDHw5CsmjAVKAFxGCiwIY044cKe/SakJO4LTlRMktMNUoj@en9GCLVzlDQUUS40jsQ32oGJhOxVJRMnia3Z6G4QqDMU7hu71XGKLln/HhaOWd9w1JeshBRfq5FR3xivmmePuCTGPnLz0NcPfAGz7JFBEWAUWbF89O7fI7gw8R877vBqGXbREGSaflDNL@R6jPoEy1q06Gk72v64zCYggbQzHUnOWqj7n47uOzXdwY9v9MddH3Q0zBH@oQ5Hj5O6REnrDMa3IR0tQ59aFmFWtPomdPHcDo1/G3OJUtWiq1wHAxd2x1hPJpWLjkLBFnO0cdPmf2K6Hs4m@vM1FleiSol4uGl5G5X8Er31n1RmFeZT@6xAWFwWzOeEhwiOqa4Iyu2tHSnQONLBSwYGyqjfO8eh7wYxBuAIjqGiUGsgbnjfmAPAjWzeyE@bU3SLcolOMI8SsFugJfThC69Tvt4Dytwka/QI@ClKqznrap8ijLBfIL4ML0f3cW13xl6AOAXgF94MY9a5hECsbi2TqYUsr4iSUEBFvL@6xKPJk4MXKzbgV2oF2u0PpltNf55eh82yMMHhCJJl3eHKnFFuqD44K1sbh1YTn3q4aaSUimP0nKgCFIZu/n7CTZ4yD2WFj8e4rLlDBnTjrTsWkDfh6omYAlv2JzxnrVB5hTID6@YYvGxszaDwPI8jzLrCgjX0ZILBZh0eX/FY63BCJixM4M9cfVIhePBMPVI7N3LO@ZmWJuH66bnPejny8RWhs1ysUWoLU/xcVpKzMIzQzRxjJFHGdAQqq/0bMh8FomTch3XW7k@fQAP9@Es8o8ym4qZ7xavfdwUP6LDrt5ozJIi2DHZaMm8P63DwOv3cxBpk9WrOnGMOrKM@pQfraZm0GSw9HgMEfUJ7DP4aAHmsN8W4M6en3uROusMp1OX6k@xZJWIT8yzjjGZwJeGbXS@wCxwLOEaJmUEzkl6Skd5hUwDkwXjB24QpeIgE9mh2IIbTdYMHVEy/7ZbR2@hAnIieNqyPRxMjn6DMEqiL8Yd8XioTzOF8xK3NDEtgVZBpb7Ukg4nh5@n9Qm1cgcVsMTnoMKM6A5vunz8qH7pWKActMC16bM48ubTOBhPLQE08I/9qT5BGTjqSmrGVlR8IdSJNcBaAC2l0wtYXUXprztiikfvBllGoEDwaxf/LEkNzL69mjfYxiqT1hSLeIJuXm2eymxxlYig@DeiX5Yii7qkuEIDAUMM9csFaAHTkxL0eChAmXVsyosBKnMEFcsFXJbwkrKbRv6cc74jUqXA8opVIj@vxIbdRmZuIyBYzC8TAQIyy/wiUSuw0c2FxSqxNn88UQkQiDXtM8ZhKmRW4jg0M8cIhEeC1nCU04JK54WC6ePyihf7aOibvm7kra/52a@AHwPhaaYw@3U9H/sa67ZYjFeN1QR8eHavsY@ACs8G2HCFX/YfRZ7YqcuNT6ilZMSkDPHD7qMqdYN6W/b7UG1SzLWWMXR7duC3Vr/qfCNKLLn6lxOpK0nTX/rlg9WOqRoQyexPWed0KIvL@iAJrA7u9DgqVHR1Hj2TfkCrtIO2ene8txdL6tqYaj@jq2C0ks/nkYYbdg577UKNlqTuIBcvnWtf93q54c23o3eNHLF@vMe@Fw5eagU6gBmBNRFmB6MO3@OAMEBRLJ2RMFVU9a/bbfvCBDygxLmDWeOSkutA0f7TNT4v747J/kNNyv56gQPE8V0os/hufJYzpRV9CgW10SP4o6MPzwA9@KKNbtjmoIoaQ76snZlg2/LKW59xA8F7SGiyKAux9znyTnZeBb3eIK3eD0a9FuYBeHI7W2Fvz66Q5yJ4wEixu9chZZtNq@Bjt2dFDWMRm9SxOb0v6VshdHp3THF/GHSqk6HrnP7ZgV0FhryEw1zCNNNp5XQcT3K@P6JZpkMA@1Glr/yh2yQ8zRaGnV4WcPQEEL0opOeqPrEiHpnEBGcPl0akzgc3S6kYYOgeiQI6JT1NL43knuIGuc7ZpNBGHOa5DYEJM6o8rgYGkv1@XPHjuN1@HFOkbP48sb85Q6QjAFqBsvwAn5gM@18ysKz3ZtKFsHyDd27c5TtYoY4VEonnzfJfbtxKpaKeDZeWVKWyDQ@ZjKpsV9QuvtjeVrvwext/L5SLKysl5rm73md4ua1f3qptaIMMnEvNy9Eu/IRvZYwKQ2dtnOJnufKzdOlZvby5VQpzp5VtDNqHp7/@@3/@9T/@K1eRH/@NP7bpx@mfTaFsNpt71vz8bOG2hL9Pd89Tzxqnz4bnqU4JqQzZ/cko9Hu@5T2abSYeiJBq9bqN@6KmjPdMNyRXTXSXdOGfchk0sB9/5KezcfQ4ih4xJ2pU3e8NL32qrqiFrXKqklpYgKfNcupfU2Q7kfe@ef8J3isPeTklTSDU4r0/qnK0U6vZaceR65P03g4wRw5efin5cuTg6iKp7wjMnKpsVp1n1IUBD9086lwwDiKrmQzMvwmQenTkk0Nn16I24KE0mb7ZHM8HU1dhh@Q7bTrny8980VSet17yGRq1sQQMD8uX2Fdd4l5x@AAuHnuVM6eF1ZXzTDKZTJgL0epNYnPU25D6Mhdk6SN0ys/AYVhDWDIwdrqgroy4gAYRGckkXZe10ORr3dw@qtakMbHCnUxZ8jzam2ggCcPm2MLNyRRQxkKFj64gU@E1RWGgbDB97BkeAEDhdZvEuBTfnhwOg2a3PTUuD3gjRdQ77JUYMreo2nci5pQzajgyrqftqEFACEoBlKsHG51tkJE3gLJd4nY8Rv0bxI27RHUhyb/VMk2wcQgaDnrTTg86c8mVKrwB7gSY92Syen0dSoc9cM1GAFJPICuaJyzy5UW4GwGaIvpNPCHD@6F6mJOLBT4@/qVslLAeUMKR@@HaGAri9vrsQDRowyNs@BhFx0dYRIZLuKUKQaFSi8qxvl9O@MDi0PPUkEsiVuF3dPhO5EEmSNKH5aI7SRPCpzFDT2ri202htCFe7YeKtOQG9WQlObRWzOkbSJVXeFaJ55SAFCyZpbvEgDVM1UWvf2HGz6ebIV5HmHV0l9xNkf0TgGOZbnS4PHXHsQAOG1fp5jE84ZQLtAdh2G0AsmCIMk2UApGDB0bQ6lkqwZ0JteBxICIYXy0OzYqyx6dJKZgMKT6f4X2Cpt2@poJYQTwgxTOxAM/uMMfBQFge/OoP@hliuY1g3G2yAyX3/lTz4iGei9MxJQF2f0egPPg4TjPB1MOZzi4kx8U01VE7hCcMVsD1f2lEb59wJmZeYdESOAIAGeIws3MWISlq0VACNRBHisBI/t@CwScxwuwFne44VictGRjY7ZxHcatRj4v8AgG2sTuDWQyU0CfNhiVcCL61awYyXv0NGO26J8HP82hPDwZ3Nb540tTkIVE83fpd@jD8SINjQw0rGNCHyzcdnyHaXHGvoyRymMqzFSdVFc3CF3ugxgVE5heLFOBDDQi3mMVJ5hSwUZzBBrDTmWUQceF8rHmLgJG47Z2ceNQMenm6WCS4w7w1vWhIkQhuEyak5/Pfut/YVDZGGJ8Miw9KIR3AHh05nJg8GrNNzl2BN4EW1CU5HrDG0TVmpGNHFtlRMIVNlxep1amBY6YrPXSZ4QxJSkPKjwI/T1P2XM5U1eONap/Ha2dSHNL1WQd2uZakM/Qk3ku@PuHNvLC6otvliC06eqNftzq0TCKzjMOEnh1BOW2vfhvRgw4xdMeSmZzbeaShdXjN5fWYRbIA4TLWOLVFRzRSzvYJmoMk9lWoXI8HtfGvL9NTbmk56zMv6bpVkAt8EINFRPC9nDzBI3ofe7@WWoB8oAuMgP3X/DCA50SCJQ/RMJ3XYWd7MHHz6TPnzEkXVjc8h/RkI4clmyFoRslmwNnS8MpG0T0pKyPZtT8GzMJHjW6rFfR1LlaoKr2ZT3Vp9hTN@Z8Nuwv5hluHmHjgWLw8zMAk0gvBNT0PR37nyqfHN4PjkT@twSZEPw/6PJ9H2N4hbEZ4JxN9OeQ1WmmBqOHcop4c0cSjhkheUT5IPs0xiQacic8SF@YgILiDAO7TjD@MD9ZCgz1@tl0Y6Zn2TZjUC5ZQQnaivuCDk4sEX/h7hTfS1vkd0KZr3Qgsj/Rp5ppqkRHwg3YQtt5yDRb1e3jSE/Rj5xA6dbAQHl8bzbXSqgcEmtcq15eHMmB/6AsDfXghis24eVm/uu6NuzKyO8PS48JKs3cfkzqpr6u@5/5jMhnO4s4aB7Z72oVVGukyxKgiLIgSplux9EeNbho/mR0joUFUFU77UVwm@sjflr4wNyzdb2lVA7NyWAc2WjnFcSYsdQNqlxLRPqvMqJ/GlA@EA5CCYCwO6eJpYs239hzjDGPeEGImZnJ/C53971nJ5Td02hBhSeul4p7JPCzS9SmqIK3ycohtabVAKXzz@OAqEM1W1AlLebVujeNkmr@7wvqA5haT/ixUaa9tW3Z5GltoMeFQ@2ta6DRCDO3M9izQWG1hxJYkiOUMJTEC41lauuWo9Llsg5USKMkwzwrZWmIyI53D3qCJO5tn2ogRdz55WnozEhAVBZpqaaYqu1u0sYm/L1r1oh1MwxqXKW2RXUUbaCSzzlHCDRk8iKjgLqIKPw9RDNc8PPGXXw1NcQTEsXSbSMwjX8M6xDXLXusmgugOXyLEPTWC8EwbcwTdRg@TBkaAzTYHE6gl@w0tDC@qSgfYYlwWZsdwP3rHWg8rkOFMyLgxxHEYwvUIk@omQbpKwP@Y4Bi41BUadGIWEBBZcwlTiOLDEBuEb2ONkJQFKpf0EuIzlEvyNUGFtYJHnTyiJ4zA/QXiPbNBPIpp3wl@ww2FRI5FVZcAwod3P9rr7jFLx8Y31yQNHDkySjN7XhwOMajgISt1LimpLFwFzStP/UwDNdlKirwHoZ0nl0w8ARBY0sCcetAZ1V4SA28YwDBMRk4250ZuWKwfakP3H8n@rXGsfRWEAoyAkNfSAcpndAU0T7BICBTISgs09TxMAapN7MzcXiJRjcRFQm2MkvUOXpCteq5ByMwK7dKhim5QHY0tq@Jcq6m2EKnk3GrKxRSjaM2go6OgiYZwY6UKPcseLGaHHLQtN3IDWBwoaZqMsSt7OAsLSmAjk/WMjDFX0Y8hiuGIIeOsL/EWM6QLTAhfEuJlS4FlYqS@4Vz7AxeQEtHqXJgviCB7jeSQyEKTi/B@3TeYn48dqvol/FAwxGAm3ohwQhzV5H6JoEn8VITO4vMBIiWD3t8Plf6kmXgsqcq93ffRIu/FawXei@29Zxrm0NqAuw/@7TY5zpcCS6P9Ry3awddPeP8lMwX8wwRK8Qpjk0QAuH049uSu8SeRXpcNx3W@Nt2wX9TjxOWu1YLtGJgtBTSlQU8ckw@SsvCsHWwpwcBP2jC1ks7dCysEFRNBmdXMpHaklylSzCz1V2clIEy1JYz7CTRH7kUUyYlHV4Mm5wWADQq/tykrAOm1BVaLUCHiiqf4U2Iqn7Q5TWFbVjKPQC3WpVsZg8BDg2AZa3vkjx8lYkVHcuywr/qYJAqkrFk6DLMJVfvpItlj5LLFR8tlyUWyaS9G4tlicgiyxYuf2cZvK6dFBlpoxzGQO7hQyYBPKgegGCaohx7GkTFfuJZ95Pbzxb5/ii9/1I1h8Q8vviwa9DfjQsxiJMQ05woxUQGp1UTDG9Uz5Yk9wLLtk4a8KGIP9zeI9wfrRvc3mNsf38SuonJSeUDd4us53Y5vBlLDEKp0SPbHuR0hr@U1feHI2r5Q7t0FzfMdbcMv/rkN/2NvwzmDC8w2@sBOY039P@f@H2HuMX9lbz2/nq//aue@5p1jE5Yzc96qlPNUFba@Wjub7ObPJhvLB39JjpNbxdz7EfwdJ/@SXF1P8iM8wK8X@tfH5FZyE4ut3ianuXK5DI/SSmUPWtn61rSJpaab8M/Wim53dZrcypSp@o/JrVV4KBSLAMnZpLpxNlnP4/9O6Y8kftinK0b4uK/VIeW0kQ2BzwLFRZ7U8kEYNblj7Q41JAGtjscNpLjzQ6MZAhidZybF9bzIKkBAnPzhYyD3b@m0GSI/Uv6YMWU04YgLnfZBfPW4EqwA04UHf6gL2u1F9IoSTuhcEyglRECri@fZVTy6vpAcFAYAk2@CxEx25Qb1wqWOMb0Z/t3Kf@WYfBQvnVgSjPjZpuyK67Ir/l9SDafjy0G/OCerfVLtwHSNA/V9yLCE/e5wGIxZ4u8E/WBEqUxgOCjo4DV7TbyUsNf9gd3/XurGVZMaqn8f1jk2hxvKDqfKefY1rKzuFWlFn2BV6mc8H1td1r@AceOFbRgno6NrOt3x5XWDLiQ4Hk1r4wPKRJHDpOZjzkqRA1mukbvy0XGA0viHQGJQAtjB6Lqfo4vdQGDDWBnMvX/l/wCg4WWyMLRWHYqhsf8Hl25uDYMhhbhM2m2HrkkKeq2jYOiPfM5Yh17z134nqGEmHpiM8NJB5Smp3lBwzdhOTWyUJcI4yOFyH1aGs4cR7w9TOvyTUKsUhhvTdT0OxqkLEyLe7WQpagJqORxaQFeEtweDcVSeo8ZNBfoZr0H52GCSODQEDwejEQE3x/EvaSCWlJIXBEf0UzqNXlBHBM1IdfEaDRxV0L@@Itox19qeFl6eS866csG6Xpw8XtdfypXyjoMIxWkSY3NhHb9cs@8lnUsmJHWAGQcI1gwJFOQJuabTwivQFMJw0PieEi0hV4IFifSX1d9k2ZMbPTyisbsfdHziFTcNTMYDb1vdkApgzVznE8jujKJ0jFQb150wy2uBAiu6YXgdrKytLxNAtOProq1BM1a0mIOWR/5omiPgLsdXPTOKjfGl6gUfg554rxDYlM6XFyXRGd5o5l/3yK1l1SPSAVTGRgpYcDfS/G63urdfOa7upkFMWcHiIYUlmbKuhVz@vETf2z3M1MBkhFV4@WYbq8tM5G6YTn2NFjkG/Wsb7Us2wLqBMMziHtAduqkyVRM/C25YDVFt73fS5jicUg3prNG43BCUa7pqwtHI1Ss/mcSQrhD7SiIJxhIbQB0cmI7cHvWA8dwpdC@vAAwId6uPgSJ7yD@Rcp3Np5mMWVMv6SkDjDWT2WIji7PT64LimTq87se4bYrWjq9SwOTw@J9Z29MU8YWsU1KXZdTjS81yvmTi9j66195ncyV1G6FwGXHHg@2pnj/3WiLTHECIR17OOmTyf/8n5ZVuoyQ6PXfs4dUL6lNZZ47OMlOv8l21bipswmSNodqn7DiYjHc402d5XDIVGoPWNEvJtVo7oFW33E92H0PX@wx79dJSs1x@4X2GLkdDzAA6BGYYHEOLXgnftWPvTIhY7uysjxdQL2Lo3nev91/BlKOfWBCOT/98vvgsl06lPK@EQ/DLFN@3e/D6LVr5R16WrP17o8GV4GXkm06yMNtX4Wn@nKBPOzi0HK5C4JydYCyjD7enx37nDUhLbsoHFKBbEgXGwaR0N32JLyuhbxLKXHg5i42jshOfXMf73ClTqctR0C6xreI2LH90O15pDH8u7S5WoItysUitj6FSGb2aZrDe7cNu/er49X45tekrbLU8Z1WklhqGOIBQiGBcfFXB66hipANchahqzNF6RDDw31LK2YqPZTPnb6VKt7f3wrPP@XRB@ElFBNxyr9NCcaPy3SktjSIqmA6DMr7gre2b6rGThrqYggVf9nF7mxLT4iDWsu6DyQ05BW2B0yMsUy4vLyzQO6xyHZbLxXzew4wot9BaiPfHQ7O8sEal25FfbrkGkf6wO@e2pGK2mONAljBXWC3mV9a@GoxgiyjjhfQLIbCQMmotH7vj6QLIhkFZ37y0AHIy7Kblp8uL6wfd7T99t3G0uus2G98WnLTzfUhu@6OhDcDIv8myWAQ8diS5dgkIjFxs@rmh/8Mgt9zKN0HyLKy1grWVYD3/Yr25ErzYaGxsbDTby@uN1saav7bSbOQw2TtVyV51@yAlOUz@2G37cd3eJ5itF/Mb7XahsLrWWtlobxTzL14sN9ZXWvnl5fZ6wX/xYrVVXG9sNL4stUXwJIDBar6Le8csB35@v3CXuMPbpbb3/w)

Befunge-97 ignores invalid instructions, like Befunge-93. This answer uses *turn right* command (`]`) to separate Befunge-97 from Befunge-93 (`]` is noop in Befunge-93),
see [Befunge-96 egaugnaL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167745) and [Funge-97 spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20031228193410/http://www.mines.edu/students/b/bolmstea/mtfi/f97.html).

Befunge-97 code is on line 5: `>"972",,,@_`.
`_` is for DOBELA. Second `9` on line 5 fixes *99*.

**Golf:** moved LMBM inside DOBELA.

Answer (score 3):

## 284. [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98) ([PyFunge](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/)), 13280 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo  anet   /112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu91&&1-2Prers 6 4>80::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*sExps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody+/='d  Float#  +- $;#8;在e*n* 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}} #@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-2/_'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51 @!00:8:8 ;;~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//   >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2AAJVQIEECAIE2Gw2eS/v7W72NNm371wQjS4UCkA1gSp0VYEEms2OmfHurMbSeuXxWDGakXVH45VXWjnCWodtjdaSHSG9OhR@0g9ofWxsKDY0/2D2nJNZhQIIgOwZTcQ@bJGoys@TmSdPnjz5dbKpe92f/SyGD3vi9MadnuMz3/R81nKtc9NV2f0xu6dbXj63LkkYatftDPum7XslKcY0xmzzgh3ahtUCN@Y7Z6ZtvTFd8MsxNnCdjqv3md/VfbBYEIs9MHtv@299Zjj9vm63PAi5ztgTHTzbQ@OM6U3Pd3XDtxwbvDYYe2b39H6zpTMIYboD1/QJfJ4BCOOM4kz7FBh75Lieickbpuc56LjJ2LbZH/jjKliKEEJ3Lefh7uOPZyJvMfaxDjkb9MzRTF60LHtumW5rJoamsc9PDg5mXXPsM8Wx2cH1/Gnr7Jnr6T19Fv4G2x36zqE/655nux3T1llO3VJzs54Fdt/Vr0XZZK6pt9pWz1Qt22AK65q9gekydGFtx4Uq881eMVvMNnYnMVUD4xYnnjNgK8HDdLfjgadzboLRhJoYWGaLtV2nz3Tbu4CUtK3sJDyC3ZomBwMyCITGXnkQu2Uyz7YGA9PnnlBc0yVvSJn1LPtM4tT3xHVaQ8OyOxDOBLwOhj6VyZMMiFZlA0HDKhpYjLDAg0EWjp2@Ga0LD4gXcu0NTMNqWwZHjjnyTduD8noqs6DuLqxej7XMHkSYQDfSzHPY0Is4NXt6VzVUCZGLqbD@WY9ZzBgMGPeCYkCWDrJFZvadVxZ7A/69rsdGgz7zrD54@4bTbpsme2MOuhCd9VvMGBtSy5EYPMZgpnShbdWEMLYJJdx78nXAnY8otduQvRZrRsJBXijfVGrddgCFLrP1PqcIYzAmDACYMEbbcVR0bzmmZ8d9duG4Z6xpGjoWHRPzzE5bH/YgRauNVQK0YHms78AXKtJmkC2I7CM@EDYmJs0tCCYTVLE5gMaJVewgyUB9BzV94epAI64n6tK3@kAhlh/3mKl7FnItiOKZdouoYxDyMwdKG614dm5B4wNUDF2C7ZkukT/BZVgKAKmH9Jq4cC0fqAJLscuemLrLTlzTTHJaNT1DHyClRpOExBxMwceCqESc29vx/aODOBApj6HqAyBKd/3ka59KOlMrbLVRhl9FlsvS/uMH7HL1FM2cbwIhD9yEnmSVd8zLnJ6a8BtpzUzHvZIAqgRY6bGMM/AzujKADCo@ZDCjoxFNynlOHfQiCbPtmTqINB0eqgW1AYyAfZ6mkhlD10UOP0GqfgaF7jl2B/AJhXWHNq/yQhaqAOiv5aWZeW4iDfA6ci4IwyddoBD4h6AR7sI7HUIodDvQHAVGg3Q9pzekcBDT87FNAlYgKkI8bLPPWVu3ehgF/BEUz7VrekCcGGdot7Dm@5ZttlQWZIM4jwvt8RyS0wEoOUBr6Ef4C2UKAkNFOFRU9Hr/6z9sdToAZ9cwHLclyPVzIHaDukedMgsdHEOCdWy9R9mCcGlMnUeHBM71ntUiTqfbY5EEZYJSvXCGvRajhnphQZPr6sBwTWAShm9yIneGPuQxzfr6GeeKFqdcKHhfb0LFUgKUNhVbYff2oJYMaOZEM0p/6LeLTBnss7iXeZHYKSV2Vk5NyFxSTa6tZjKdMhCcukZOYIsvo5zPd6e6i89ZBwhlOMDytdJABMx2LgThaMo6kglxHkCX5U63V3NkGkPfxNoFlt@kkvT1MUWOsJc8wQDWc3J4hFUE9ej2HL0l6vg50ol3AYy1y5o6MHMfmTbiKZpTjA956yJvsT3oxMzXQ8gS8CTA0djvOnaOKQaTjYoDARLxqeLH03G3GU@q2NEkkmWrYqhty24l4tvQjKqAs3iybFSMmlWql2eiR/MAYC4QDHIaM2EkZWx9J5aDfKg36KIQAUFtbwBM1MWSGjqQg4c9lQ9yWpo1iVCpewNWQUzuwowDnpq6FxIGtTHehjC@gpxPQJi0iemmabYiLRNaNSDY966x156DXT7lCSsUeIGNieodEOsgMi/ILi8IT4lcpot0BtRhI7SmyYpK0wKqxvYDTFoQcaRsEHw9x8MANE71kRpFUoFuivf3kxaANa2zPrR3d8wME5kIcBOT9xCYyJAalAfCLHPaLKvk8vnpRnOtzfhuZlf5Erjum8zSpoGFj7YO5BysDbJzT7c7Q70DTcKxIYpuGObAF5wHSuL5wFtmOxByVERvqHpdafXebNrUKwQyzyQNaj9Ue6Jv05FdCFlcAUEL5Tku4LMWNEqDmsF06hDgfCZx@SUGmcrAS3lBFoIuHYiMt3Jo3EDAF10LWukF5c7mjI73KrPJg1M0dWDVSjtMGjOjVe/mJDUTOmE2FoJQsEavw4HeEkFVpxyo8qMOyyHrXn8OYCfMInD2iKua0VWgvRtg9h3bmQMUEBmCxSDTPrweQLQ6RkkXeqJAjqLGGoq/YRVBnQHXgJYP9Nf1/YFXAsZv@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@JpjJ0s65UmFArSS/TVjusMB4lssrZRUrR6MllbB1GsWYln42uJRFGBQSmMq5IfFZMpnWM7ETdBFEicnsYBqQI/NaPrErxROpdMhqiCfKC0ByOHRFy9LEL6zWQ9mYpD3GQ8DQPRSjwOmDEQCR4VGil/CkFHTz/jiNlLpSQiUBhj4@@aLAFuOISfjv5k@OYNMm4OoxlSWG@o8/HgQATIHNpBWBU9Z4bggVezzbATmUrjY6fNx3h7@Np/eCCZI6qtj48O9p9WKJmu7p2BQKV0MGzG80Gc0N2WCu2oN2yZ0rwwwDPBZExygrMhmHjHMJjiMAqmGDwTkb7SYAugAaPFKQHVYUqvP10Erwv53ZsqAwEhd4q5THgzgizx4HPzFCZ5AN3V3vHDqUm//hkIU8zwejj5obi8AGDNrHHHFn1iwA51z7FaJXZII04bpGugLRCuW@HMhu3YCnYEweDUiSbEp3cgBLmhqIlilDUVBgG3rREM8GM4O4SyHw7AgISAgQHCbBhqm@pzYm4yAyaJ828wEps3FHrCpUjV8CatE0Y7YBz0dANY@DS4U5mdAkDgQJnMfJ9k@RpgGBlNDYxoVuKmMoIcaeg24q9l0ah7aHldRC8MpLALdNuAVRxy41iSsHbIDBDxO4Bpc2SJvgha@DFG@UT3Ekkci@7yQRZSGQ4QMFPBXCRJ745hDF0TBgroyyd/2L59brmOjUhW9wE0sKIy1sEM8HnoBTLa3T3MPViM33nAAWPXnLUIbqNQZ5FreNC6bKfndBy2BgGQNFWVE/ahjXO20Gn7@gBalPWGELTbcezxDA2aZjgLXFhHkuczUxgyQ@HVV9ALsPmFngRYUObjwy/3obfW8tks5D@wZekJCxmBMltGdDTYJIBY1@gh3WBNfmkOumN3ipw8R8wC@TQVSg2Tz8vpID9DrkQLf0NRo42cu0A7D7xagWle2fdpQIRTkYPxgtJPCR@82UAJYzPO6BqgYgrotQqf1C8yrtPMFN8Kqu5cafcdX898rgKLxpeEwwPFYrKXia/EM4qCb5m8WK7KMi3zPINcagJ5tI8zNXNgj0zTyKAvdm4sMMxFT@C5ADWn8Nj0gmLyb4CDMOZs@TupFDJ2yl2YNs80dPIn3aEpmUbXYfIpjK@iJZOhg@haLVMBzIP0i4OyMJpY45J8Zwhj2pbZs/qWf0irED0bB24qMW8VuZbw3QN@MwHwxDJhNMJnWyadDK4UTPoou8PDPwVOTlA9n6kcpa7ZyqxNoD1yHLeLU1saTajkQtT3hUfG8QYt1R8BAB5rn/p3L@jnHx892G882T35pJIZem6mZzWBR7TMRh9G8j1oDgsezBvOd@4D7Vi207egRAHIN2e9p47jc@EBl0Ju98QwYgDj4YPGw8P7T3effl1kjnp0qz/s6ZjH0upMgBDGMYVZCsZwmg7IFvZwISQQLo7uHz0MoHz67OHhbuPB/pOjkwiYV8OepWujzOCss6hAn2IQpqlZjvqjXmt6jYrG6FNTKILZ4ICzzGBgzhQF3gq68URxSKqiB4rI2D0qCs5p6zhr77Kclt3aajX1YtEstIyNjc223m61NnJaMd8u5nP5LLw2C1sme0vBFcUc0bQVmPiUEM6eYRqQefpo6kYg4cA43ACJZTw3X6HvkswZ@by5ubGlbxlbW1t6brO1rueKm6ZZ2GxvZLNmQcu2m0WtuL40c5FsoGg1sfVp@gtaHc6UkCcwvwR8ppoDzzzIeheslcvlCka@vbWea@WzG63mVjZfbDW1Tb25ZWbbG@taTmsZOa0UxAUeC4wh04UKQ6nSBtE08FI08ExKQWcarWJaNw0W1gXDWV1HFjMIFsZx4CA8NtBjKJbFAWbgnkf3YFEc56eEewHd@7gkPpFkyRo6ioBFCogr46rbDBy30DFcE59aLQZWKfjnPP/FkQTkSy17hcAvcFU9Ur5LTSP3c7/dnnLOkfOZgl1Zb@K8Ts58TX16NVsU9prX3MAhvA2Cx9fi58K75jU3cAgvz@HhGv58cDM@84KGwAoEDNf858Ka8ZgTMIS0SZCi@wQmfkXyW7RJQKQ113thpBD2FsHm6/@NV14DRe2GWP5HauYN5AQksYcOyM8PLVy0aE@1GCkcgZ9KcjCNMD2Lhj5cdsmcz4zslHM5Go@3fcs@c2icHJoaWVXLY3sOY/fPetdjtmFkQa@poGEeAjlmQe68frNNrzkBsI@dnYUkD5riFT099Kx65il9cLJ3Xg6mp62nkm@a7SEMejJNy0bzDcGUrSKFbDeb1qKggAncPRF85wQrsadDGHjm1A1VC0a5uEwELJrPOZ8cHlHApk5jtum1DjaFfH/o@hBLfP/rN1pQCderqKuPaegXGhq2eYHVpbQX1piIihZ6za/dSSdPiCHTTSANHdeL9V5omA@aal9RurrbxxGWqG4gUHwBJSyhNZ5zPvUSfOcnUmKE5Ok1FWZbfWZc20vjOw7zYNg8qZuZlSCeLg2vcRGWMMIHwZZJkVysd14j5ogPByOiDvQ5c3I4m79gwYZNtjz43aE/5G/c5XBTjVoD/C1rrSJkNq83NROEY71pmUvq39XPhi1HARmPiowZK8wJOyk9TdMp7Z5@xo0NNM4vPi@ga3U6IEmI76JgF10Y1dBwNHNBn5tIxLOH3kBpQmX50IbIRq2ivyQFt8ffi4JYYi9gaFiMNatHr1tUekhcRC4gzBGicXuWEkGaNYPmnt4c4yC9@@FUhgmSaAPsp2KkUtl17PDCJe/olqrF8bGXpPhbW/Nj841hHCXzBlYZviFM4VPHVGaxReyGioU@zOrrPSXXihgXMvdg0nhimhOUZmwUo6d7QFq@qA7zHKqPXsvIHTspAwZc7sS0hNgn2Ql2PixaRBccTLRqw@lZHjbt3iJmOrvuOEkTt@bRKzIZbc1DbIukJa@rhKb5fMExfFzBXkBot@ByfPEYl@cjlKM6i5BmOBf4WyhldJ1zk7/n93lv5ubqFhxL6RFJWMbczqV1vRcBJ97F0zyrB8I/EBPNtmo01OW7NYLtCfnC4PX1WsC9UPSaj/yzuYXxjd5c9@mGE8yIRMdzt2wMntVzPHZM72W4hIJ5Hn/PbwZRtFu6rdDyUdQ8P5rI1ICpYlJ2ATHovY7TKxQ7GR1eCylm6LaxIxHf27LMkOVp2s0sL5CvHFsT34V9xVnGPbup7mglw8UNDhHjkm57Ht8Ta5iLCwgkiruW5hfuIFukmGqGD68XVYBrdC/0cfD9ObqjRdgNuqPBmOR1EB8xwlYRDL7LZfifJ7WN5am1bsfTroHdvKkQkco965nQ@9H7WpWyXFb7wBhaNnt7DtfuDc2hOZfBHTVfmbjBf8ko5vaZyopirIrJUZxAwqnRMNQbMf68Va6x40fbUgYDzBYa@Y3i0Vx@NwDBfoAj9CdgeIKG6xE79nAwVblTo0D76XLMdQdBy3ZaU5lEnw/lSMWbhbAp6d8z6bd0cMYHk7gUVtnIZrNCKIpMd09Zlg3a1sO4ryz@nkqYXCYpT8Jiz@lGjPPTmMy8QtVbZ56Cc6C34065RTMKFHhrK2NbtumP8X1LRtt0nN6H1B7w25aF8h5IsbhEdFMtXpOlxKY5Npk28XDSpdleNGHC@yIxmgXE4Zh9GSFEJ2lvVcMKCjfQQDsz1uVTSJEp35tSgR6e5qX4JoveYkFVTMZoalHdXNoYufjrNM2ezj@jwsYyeFvq@lJ4obQi5GpaBcOVM75WNll7jc2wrMEYkGW1YFDUNfsmWZeMJvTWq6EXfBYGGjn4m@Ot0srkongDC3iEje@pdbmIFOU7NgzjfN3tmDgO6uH6uXBdxJeD@fe5yD3s6x2TnylbxjgnUyO4w5qPHifG@ZMkJb4/zYBofJPIclKAxnRmjr3gOxfgo7EB9Tns3zzLN9PuDdrSdFNDVzNzlx1uEBPtrtO1u2aX7xkKbYuaB1Ckz08DLisE5L/TNRjxp@h@pihme06vdxvMIn/k3NJx2nPztI9n1FoQ9YPgjvUmeIjPjbOH0M0Tgqi/X9RuuuYQeivP8Z2BqZBtUdAeTi7x9yIuGiwD/byzVktnFAAjwffnhW/cFLGjO/5gQJ/GoDf06EVRFTpauGTIxqfOKUmiS@a4HfWN02@qwlE94N9HUOELmE0Tz7ngFiZO2WbHaRpd66ZMN03dt62zTDDHxK1Lh72DCJ4spjxAZ7VnAXrdsYr0Uon6H@PncFGli@kq3rGFhvlUUGJ7Q9cdI6UHc9E0ZUBbsiZnlidcZXp/RjhZzJc70LAoV2LlcY43yRC4cy/YobZkzUUsVC4kS5LaUUJXzCyIOdrCeaup7aORNrW@zl@LpKmZ8lOmIuvDHzLxKrZV0BSkFZkfBvcpmppa7J7bxdndYce7ziT5skALBDN8za393Q6eAr9F5fOKhr5Mt8VnUR3kehncLw/fBtTm0Fy6xJNfusZD4bSeojsWfBrwgXodLpyw61kDj7@Z0s7NFT2uL1tfDzWeP/YWddYy23wVBk03yYx9x8VTWyCcKIZregZO4iNv55IY52O20wEer/TYJHAQdm4Rrq@UzyWJsO9UvnhsdnTc0vnQwt2dvTmUAlBnF8xvAvq1oe5ZXxs6vjkX3uyi@U3gHukdy/hkCvMBsACjYt8f/0w1BXS6jvyLruXRgZnAsGTiComMky3SWQNGDvOGfDMLBeHx8uVzMxGRS@w3Z8ohC/alhwZcqkB/fW5a89YAnAENPsdkWjb9b/k0vSu@c6lq/saDZclfDPuDoSc@81OnvUHRyfH@Gbl7FxawSuU1cGjW1Xv@/An0yPQuSG@iM50YF8nzX1o9p8O@LGYZCHsgvKF4P4fg7kO3/kT3oUXYcwiY0l7Ay2eXaHHmROFc0nsNNGGuM8WyLX/5LJHv6zDaCr5YGN4B4bHPzEN8q/c@FIJyMh8jD5dKsiADjI0eqhXg@@481nRN6EK5MoNwi9zyzswAWjymw/9oDPUPRKlfJGbuBasVot@xzYvo@G/polMJO1vHHvoKni9Yupw@6WQKSzuZEhsVCxFaYYmv7T96loySDO3BvUnENWGMOfR644lp4XaIGUq0bJDyFjPn6dDBQOWBSVointJu0Rvi7A7w/Br1AQ@ceYOpJ2PX9G89GoMeZdh/YBq4CHpj2o@dRyDfQd82AC7cf2ry42lTzGV@RIz20DH0HuCndWMyxwR2TucxGbfrA7MJ9dubmOYLbPMAP9B9fYGARdORNLgMTTfSitVrmu4rmmeMmBeNl6cz9Ik5ooHLYoLhDVLxDYNL5TjjN9VcZleMvIHj2PxNXDkLH@3Rcu4D/QW9br/4r@Im6qnucO74b7q0R6H6AX50clFxXbPp9Pgbi7CgJ7Qtvs9Bdy3Tyzy07OGI3AobTAFxbv4Iie8mzqqbpAIGGlKwxBpuM8Zdc4J3zgzDQE4@1z3agTB/8DO1pfn2@526ums4uConDB@4Jhc5m3YDWw/3bPOdEk2omBEwNd0YilNON2W112/26bVw8BKp7admE8/@Nelsqq@P5kmW02fYhOPMKbKArWHjL7DEExgeJW@eMZsd201j3BrQi5j6xVxCCZJ7bJnGGz15q3FVpEXRlHVGpyHw3EY1vU0PZKCeqfhd3PSZ8ZfNpQfng@csyAz7Jq6BT68ELSQlx@sSHTjzV/1DVuuaYuc47lqERh@Ykd8quwsJFcHD/9H9TzPQJTcKG6g9YThSOsDIbt5nAJkfurb43IbYnjie37ZGRwPUi@W4izgLFisPUeDDGwGa1hYVAmrPHvb4dEgnsq2s36KhHgiGbQdMPWLevqmY9rlC@qJG10vkuKTyJrOLCtd8s6WICRJc1lAeBnJZGEx856zlRtkk7mrVMhyxo8KG2Oc6D7kXXrgqCR7KwKNvZuA9OXx4dKIOPG1uKwimMXG34tDq4SojNbjADRBDpmvSW0@nxrFLnqR7aOrcW66YjcyYvdLdyHIt36GH5xIz9481Ze/hoYoBFtQRX3JR4IPLiVOfxRs8Bl29afp6Rl84zEJf058vYn5y8uhhanJOmyX2uq7TN5NR773j4zRwKPbp8VzvaOwDaFFtZ7Qw@uG@piXnkPwzm5Y0FzHXOSktgnRiwmAZKuwTfmT4RvHMcAZm62Q8MD@HvhcZvHfL5AsLC/lYP7c62HLZ1kJEUeNmW2phIxnZvm66qJ4s@C6qzzNrgBzWoE@GfxbupkHBYz3jrs8XPpZtWJgVglhWbKT4sEha9jq1@pYCLaPTRVNG937RjGmatgjPx3ob6pXlF1bWdIB5gknPOb/Fcrcphj9K6KT4QFWKdeM@@02lD@w@gy9cPRCOYGwu3MWzDEDoXJjb4C9Me6zbCtcjsHTwPcDedHmQL81brJeFG5TO2Vbxep7EyUZSKRfqKgIOy8/cgpvlCqUmnhroRxQHlEnMC@YBwFE3jCFOXUPTUxkFTCT0VCqZlESsT0Dg6aPyNYzk0Tl7aExllg2MWIou9GIUHtWsJNiqzrYrLLeeZclkmWssAn4MfdPQLLO2FYCGvtDq2JCFIAekPQ77Da41xGM96AUCuLUaW70clbIl7QqVmJRkVq/zHONDieyPBqT67SmPXlvV65XVuKLEV@Ondoll42Fws@eZ84PrU2Ehs/gRGQ7xy9VCOqTTMcRmmSvaAvEVtdJ1dbsFPEZwaSi/y9VFcV1kJ3gg489/ryWU9ZFSyr7l6T1ACOrchA6j61zs8HQDdA0Gukua10gdVI9rqlL2doUON66jD6rr2cFJUSgKEwo@wfKEr26EueCUgxsz8Ny/zwmD5yY8wy0SDmMFhTKc3rBvw8Cp5Xc9lR1bdKR/6E4O6Qm1p7bv4uprK80OWcvEDe@kqYE2G/Qc5ywUpf/897h6NNLXIM7RB8mTnsNIiqiWQSOdZIbhDCHXAZA3puuIIAlEsm74Q9zVQ2o2yT2JWgxIbxtQuxJoLaNkuOqyvd1jpuyzOCrfQd05ZaudWN19@vHntWy98o71M@Z//UYmeSkQJ38ELMOT0ywIUr5Cwop658F74htn8upI5gmGyiwsMVtzwesDlY9yIkN9FgGNOc4gaDY4/CfNiSE1CgVGCTRTPQf7g/ukTJAI1rwg9WV0atpG2ZK0oHrQwMCaJNC81VVWE0O@20Q59lkeEkQVcDpXJuig8lCrb6IqLoyyOmJvGQl50MNo@SzYOCJ7qP2tX7kfcNb16AG1zAOzOaSjGuc5NZevUHFWG5XtKplglOGgWsXai9NRLqucjjb36xkvQOrp6eijbO4LwLrjQqy7GWx5@48fXK6q1ezbt54@ZrJ8FS/zA3XAJlYvnxw@2T8@2T15dgy1cBWwtgN@rDbgNUhFdFK@6/RIYSXgBacWPoD/hLYJG0S1yMmkFD3TTEEFrmVFXuXGCGuain1D9HnxPTPifz2A4GnQ80lhzwBUoBOxIdaw8FwtJRNxhaZBojLLJ@neVUPE4LHFObyUUCWzCiBLAWTdElVscWF3uNttMHYjlOVo25kbBDEWplcL/XkR56Lg6h@k3APd837xcnMoy8tNYZaUG4KGrkGcg93Dh8@e7k9HCzp54rqVrbw4zM@ZM7Y0PkkRqFYkHToiIu7WqchMpgjcKjozrrHZ9C9MKJZgjkafRyYKpfzL0oQwATMVVBxeF1JIIkE5QPkGBZFZXQNtaxTJYtBHR8Bd8iKGTOBADkEHGVdlATlGCrBVfIJiIFSBrqDpPSEmLvh13IuKP@mgxWHRsI8eerzNLeiqwl7HY/Af6ZUCU67ORkx0Z1qdKSwHv55pd6DAQdhkmfdRbJUjQl7leZfD/KLSYshT65VOy9o0XBdn9KGX7ukDLxAGY@yx45sl9nrokB6ggJmE8gXpy9a5nnGqWq45m/QLwagWROOg3yJ4hwfHFZTOuGhG/D1Kc0MbOyoIxNV9C00dvouq8bkKBa53l6PcERphg66SZoE9oQEylBI8dm55FgxxqRLaKOP0gFNiaUTBUW08aYBiuz0PZJIWdN8gofjY1YJwotLBbn66W7GZHAOaVEORMc1kCcN6lesaQqErvcAx90seeZXCEWQvAjO@vaIogLmOZQc64kuoNJ4mQEvMd4e4EbsavxYlyEKJTErX7/ciAecoPz41M@9//Ydc4fGpD@bvCPMoex9svypsbTD/WuCjaWD7Z6EtB7bvctuLDFbZdaWwk3xOtAsvPAsP1HlPlmKzRUPWEOjLpyKFlY4V/vnhE@YZqCMZq7SvjyK1hYwmGKkwqw@0cU5VjcF5CpOanMBJ1D4HSgHyAjJBKQcFG0rPdOsJ1BBaymQw57jerdKeeHPEt6KRwtDXQ9R8DbJYppAvbGgZyKRyHgAkNV4dPNfLASaTJWCN0rk1qLxsGmx7e5vJnqH3zEqhzEkks6q/WJdfhhldhbASHy/UGMSBKJMY4FcV0RKrekpLYlTsz@JaHFlby@EUB0JhggwQJInOdqD4B6ROR6AKyNmGMT0JTuNgHAR823YiOqkDQAoA4rC5NufpVjk5q4vrMZF2qkarQX6OwY4xWEmeR7O1F@zUP7XrQk83A/r70RwKtsH8T@Yo7@Z0iIrNriuZTsyqiMbSsHvHtoNLWweQW5bIZXLrGa2QjDQ@WYCC/GKLfwsgoY0DzzBM65Uz8Hb39g8/PXpyfE3fHoWMzwaLs3h1O3WqqOlaPTTEw3xPI/X@Qeb40f2DAJXRXE0mZTDE5CDCbDbnpTab0wWpP@fHoq@nTR7XEtKytwVMu3yVAzrLcx36xDcTCbjHT2VeSzWRvLyq1berp3bsWvJv52mEj6lrSFxgOvVIH3x8NpuYxfAGmBO8AcZTA20fGqr6wJPgvnM2URwiHCIePHgABTiApGaCUIvYJ2TgiM8BTTRc5fgVNB6xPj5PRGq9wxxFQp4El9Vg05ooZBWaSLu61@1ZTQm68BaqJuZ6xAJFWaEGMtUb9Cw/kZSE8loQJlBxrLiyZlQaqbRJJpHEZk6w0myZctMAXlKCRgDw4k@GXpc9cQaR2a0HZmB6CvIIezDkGyZM9umwD@Ha9Hlq0owxSCgKRAZExcOs8nE1tCyh23SUQv2xkF4NNZyKgqv9Vj4xSqpdc9SyOsDAE8k0tPSPNBCsQu0rWGjSd2rHgcdxDH@MB1ujKP0gFbejCXC9pquW3TJHCdTZVqqDhIru8Yvn53FgqbM0QHp29wLNnDMKd4OGqPuiRUyU1c40tq3wnpoZxcVbW6j3ro/7rysMUjz23YdghP4p0e7rA5YYkhpsj6mMrInThJ32fDfJlCpXJmWzVIrG1fAhD5CbMWibTEQ4LIEzkYlMBWoHXT27hZ831oDVNFWtg5kSSbJVnFPbg64cZ6OSEoyTIEqJwFawblkJc8SpV@WUB3HQXyLVlAx1Qc/xJgXGtBjiIC6o1Kx6N6LSb9ICOVa3tkqiNqZZzRYDsrjO5dUMgJ3DQgI5FfArtIMA1vC6ErzXBtdlgS3c@8y0bRMQBDTT16EP1odAZG4yHdxRlZ5cb8FFLJ7FT4S6Ecjo9LUX@/HLHm7bWc2UaXqmfAV96stT7FTbolsdZ/77jJopXyZWe5VxBgSdZDWx2q1oqfW1VGrVXkus2tjV372LszpXqyBJNFQYJI0gkLLaS5aBnkHyqKza5VV9O7HaquTWKAZYYZh2CRHeeRn1clW/yqzehZ46DS4ub7yJVY90DWdVVbuC/GELWc2kgWYuUTUrXVCFya9aqRTmQV1tYAbeZU6PU8SzT48zNIFUFvJoptMXzW2Gq4Y1ce16Lo5A4SwqGhh7Dhm7OLXVCAKj9qZgyX6O3wLZgyf8Ga7kMFo0Nr3oAECe9rk9YxH8Lk5qILlmZ67sGRA4SgAS0ZrWk0lgJj/7WUwrMDmxulNY752n4vlsGV5aOc/y7KPVU0XJrdZiLHZvta7rfgOG7pm1y9MHxc45M9u5wuua1VZfFytP0mf1J0@@eNd492I0Tp4m4rG9o7eytgHhN9kW/W77bLLcgueWihJjaxkpllnT7m5mMi9fvgShF59aVa0GQdT6u3fJWrxe28QyLQIUT@RyyWPLsjLsdOC1WvArO11GV8bVY/xJpRIKucBLqXG3nZ3@qI2G0a7Z6Qz39TF3t2JD/Bz4Iu6jL58/f46G5/SwN0@5O4txiEyEKzX0fIzlsrk//8nKVfrySWP7z7/Zz5gr@DnCz3euHqH5WMt/tLLy0f37GxtpwBY3P/nyydd3d3c3HqTzT2r5nQ0lu7L9Z3@6spLLbecyK3XP0@rx2tkXci67Iat//uN448mTr3keVhg@60wDI76L8NNYPs/O2Bt4ztoM/8n8phUx62hutt@w2JuYpmmxMf01cKUBh9YVYj7TzwrTqjub/@17R69jfqyayzx34evHXscKxRg3ggFs64HtPFaNbWOwwlVsnKlUKmDc/G//FuJXPwU46DPehlc1H8AqjGNVpUJR3saqBTBouRyk@39/4xvTeblXg0fe2MzJO3V41ujZlmLVEXhWq4cHLFfNrQlC0op3tbuRyLbfBVHkNKYVN47ukdUyHfra@NVtGLRC@9G03CknVE43/ItzKrGJcxewB7XOnNh0UDILFwj/PEYUBCREVMTNwoEIizs8nw33/FTX1zZTG7l7dvm5eELDL@95inceFlbuvXyQyWxXQRrAp1S6dxo0wgzbLMqOcw@nCNkIkV5mD0MEV@VsMSen0@l7GH6k4DOKTTDIOJJYbAq1MTaxsahTjAXR2CTMh4bbx@cv/v1ffP8vvkd/36fff5JiwcY7pXZerwYP0JBcdeXLU2EdTT3ApOpPmZb9@G08vx4/BhM0IS30nZQoFqtW8UX/wkYm@s64CZ9qaKEQkyjzwzHBiAKkxqTYu0yGYZWw86A491ZKK8VSoZTLNNhMSe5BNcm5zS25Xs3lc0dQdZpMFbcVCQXQd@BZgT/6hye04nuFXIQzBbn@rLDqrZ9ZFi/FarFavc4bdzVaSzc9T1WlDNSnkqURLXnsXIopwNRSqadA3EwQOTynqRufZylVbQgzGhz4OoriAFQp9kt4qhKLXcJTf7dWe7cWpFyrCsO2Uq@mRIbgozbu1VPK1VVNfZEql8U/SI7l0IYPfBj8oCD1K0XZfgHAatNg4xtOvODcQ@gcOL3VxottAJ/arm1XnD36qQ3ErlJ/Ua1tT4MQmbt3L6VCLdwDANXVOkuCWKooK7WFZQCA9QSDoQ3U8dX2VfWqtn11tb0N/9v0vhJfcL3avvZPn8mzIMzEv45UdVrLVE8zor1X62BXM1V0UTOnYKjCF8JBryPFLpEgWa2u4FCrotS0Qr5O0gV7xB7xx7bhH36BFV3Q4RG62fxl8xBBmNCZu0ixNWCzmZK2llvP5EcfFfZzwKs8TDony5k1NLzFvh9Eti0phuOgLT4c2iKHl@@/@t/xd/r@qz8AK5QTr44l3@Zr/Hv4Bv9e@/h3YuDf09f4x07e4N9TH/8eNfHviYd/J6/xb7eJfyd9/Lv/Gv8e@fj3rIN/UqzCGMioqzvZXvY8q51pZ2CwWBaGCN1sV2sBn2RZk2XH2THL9h2tBSYT/rJgsrJtlu2wrJ21NQ08weCzrI@mNnw68NcGKC78WdksAs@eM0ilh9yXlOvT922DJU@lGou/NEGsVDU1qxasRh0VdYEsWY5lTk8zXNpmuY0yKfm6umKNxv7jB41GBtvv6SPnaPJ/dNSPWpf@94@cR0dO34H/o6OjR6fAiaupeynlHjyVampbfHZi1fLOaUlBeg@aViyzvXNaXVfQXEhBa8mhW@oDnwlE@FZXTqX4BfTnF2USG8oX5@WLMhlCKzc0RAARjBsgVlmIG@AC8U6fZ0g8uIDnnOCSDY0X4BmYuCHz/OIUxWUYIIX/gI6o9R/g3/r/1v@jZyxRqyehDVxebSfoSeJfMnl5dXkl3tVkIiEsiW34QwewY5TLqyoaKdAlmGqJZD15dcXd4J1IbnOAVUxju0qRJwGBM8XCNCld/kr8w34xbfGcxssgMVdWE2Lp8/R0lM0my01wCVc/9Le0ipYs0/6i1WZNq//Zj3EWRdtJUqD8RrmsrXFzbiNXLm8Iy2axXC4K82oisXX9qWZ3tAIINhsbyWS5DJadAGYWrAHMIsAU5jyAND3dKGO7L8eSmH/ODBJZnJKlm5Xickm@ezchLiLbGQySd@9qW9m3b0OnRqNluY0Guq@/fSs3ZNydVNnKgz1bfPsW@FA86biJxw5fF08oGvsoV6UUthwXSrkJ3kzL5CZpdnVP93038cYapGXc0O7JSboNIZt13NP4T7/7zW@exiu4X4VcNzQEgKmw/PZ2YaNaLWyAuVAERMirfANUopPa0pJXqxmZF5fJq/GY8NKKm0lyvYqjP4tts50qNF4PH3Z5FaMqZRv5ZKI5NpOX4BK4aVtb3JFtFBLF1Jb4q6wkWXWNiT8coa2nNtY21@7hEG00/0F2W77UK/FMJn5VudRLOIF3VTbE3Tt49lS/e3d9C1BazJZPpUbjwe7JbgMvIcYNCtAPM3Qk3i3h4vPAjddotjW/Va9h8eqn8XipfI8qXyvmWSxeFuGUOHQDrLjF@4CY50lWG0@hjwjszG8tNmDa5jr0ytApSwPaLLaZZS1cb3eZ026vgCNUIWvi1gjP7PWCC4suHLfXurBa5ooUe/Jwd2//JJ3bBnkhd7C7l84dP7sf09Can9jJex3tT/d3Hxw9gwhPHu7vHu9/fPj5/rMn4O5Jr9w3umnq5tA0GxfD4cVr9sqyGhZgrze0LMsxXMhEwzTNAQQLnrJpMtOwPP3VK90d0MM4I3//o2@//9H/8P53vvv@d779/ne@/9Ovvv9t@P0e/L7Lv9/9N1t5fP/0q3/2u@9/@3fA8T/B74/h95OffvWb3@A/sv8J/P5LxO1PxC8Sjv8kgPWrP/3qez/@6Ve/9gP4/Uvx@8H136//ZP7v@99a/MN43/vd5WG@@2/h9/scVhD2u7/N3fB7Lfxv83C/9oP3v/Hv@P@fiT80/s773/gTfAnLP/3Bn/2X99/8D7lc8c/@9ftvf/f9t773/lvffP@t77z/1j/Ovf/Nf61lo6/fff/9P/zrP/r9v/6j/4X@f4/ev3@b//c/@Kd/@X/85X/8yz8Sv5/A79@B6Sd/@R@AdP/uD3@E/9/7w7/74x/h///2r/7uD//F3/3q/0qGH3LD//Mv/w1//82v/@e//a3v/PVPvvG3/@Inf/vDP/zr//PX/q/f/M9/8z/@wd/8z99Exx/@5K//@Ff/6pvf/qtv/fO/@uZXC97fXvr@6hbuX/0SXG6fz9vAuU25PtTlq58rP78INiapAJ3QjUMsByLx/bHJylKWZRl/QTv9/j95/5u/AuT/GxAQbP8T2OCfW8DrO2RhX3yBvDHqz1I0@aOkvvgC/cVw/guwxao0Z4e9RDFXTK2BlLy2tRVO5m1PwHwHYrzNgGyfvfcWQHxB8fnDvgiCQd5@i4JBOCaCBeGmM0lhcJcsd//pV//8x@QRxkXnX5kCmQ2co6FXMfjbAB3fQd4wKW409HeQvbz/0Tfe//gfv//RD9//6FexP1E2ttK7aZAKls@RQ8D8LcJhwMJtwkFADce8bIWtSDkwrGzjzK6kpV6@hNyvgAkGcGtSfh1sklYls4ZmiJgCG@MTfil8w7@0scXQAi4jcoUvS4HX/RSrVCopaVTB6UEMClaMM2LVIs5B4XxLBeBiJB4n3SjC2IiN7hMUiFlJPWWNtcqIR0yhQ5UgIF1J6PRU1nJyqlh5AAlWRg8YwkLgKeklfF9WqsXKqIrg3lEWAEbqPiQJoSqYu1H1HdgrBBPCS6MH7yArxUoqVS2CSwULmaLU0g1KU8tT4ajsKZYSU5/wxd2qO/cY@0jWijKfJAVUMhEa36lJaAwIwcH/NLUmikP/gZF@axgf6mlE@OFu3H8HnSm@CABwFQU3OcJPUTA398B7xEGlKFn4pDgEwFyKz4Cx0IGEnJSUovpNkQXShzx88AMgt6sSL9Dq6qqEVnldbhzBoBRGf@5ZyfN1FxdhSQotMbmwJaMz7hgLCohbC1ef0Bh27cEavDX431@hfeBUpvKatBrH2Zc4E6l@lOK/e/fW2EeAA/pO3CSmpNadDSfGi7udSsk5SLjqgG2NipoiQDh/Qf8p6UVMYjGiAWg0af6Gj1ohdwbDe5FfcnhRkTBnuXUN7TgbOxwOMYaqptV0WnxV@pKDKgwq@YqvukrSJj/O2sMzIsE8xZbER1hMK2zQESG6AzLJklLMMFGMY9Ijr3PfGcEwJi3Laa2AK3lJMWV0UsphK5b2S1l4f90plSrvtI1NCb5kH@JdlOJ0KNBT13RNdXsb6aJ6qdAkGRpB/i1I1arYz8A0qXq8fwLBT46YlsuqDIZAlxubuY38Rj63XijkN3PaRmFro5AvrgPHLWTzuZy2tbGxVdzavJrPne6l0/JmQd6u/qNrz3/3j@Y9813xkapfsJGKCxPKlVTtVfgm21Xc5iCfZuUyzd0RSldr2TT@5dbX4Q1ZTmv5zfrKSu9SQQyc0s7OS9xIArmWLhUGI8Y78DDpjsTugBM8kAYu9DKxNefwqCy2YeDV2nwrhqzlgdKhSk6B1Dk4aRB9ylO2AVDC5eVl5CfFVr780mfVKgx2lMMDKQZtuMuCXQmK1VK7Kl0A3Rq6Jvl2GGtZn1t4y43asrxBTx/jkTBVil1dXbXDdTKy8hgtfF8Z5NIE89VIl/7/55f35HJKbl1Z1xRtHf9vMOTw//bhc/CfwzfEWs9J21zRUxUvgnX0ViW8LJ0lkpetSssx6OBYuV2p1VU8Il9uqU2nNVY9fwxDcUFAlXiz5xhn8cDTwhvk8HxqJaNn1EYDKNB3YHxOI/qd3Ga@tJJxMypuqk@0WXInV9gEl1M7cAKXPLq8mHbaKrXUIEePoK1AvFwpV8hfbQs9kFUoD@arirm4FJkr2Y5tXuFG6pLeBh56afDtRyU5ly/K5Vp5Ygc2U65f3eubLUtnp1k8t3c5N2KhIF8F4SBpHN3j/AtL9PHWJ9yhX8qeZpMLImchMmSZciptC@VSVdpQUgNmWMe7b2v17UDtVFV69@7diPZwlQ5tX2zmym0U0Z1JOJ1wF0Suuxo35gsTYxaNJ6gi7DHUHbBwmz3EUxm@w04cvvv/vmksCLHX1ekq4D3X8bxfIMx93T7jXg8srpoo9PpExxsPvL7ldxeEeDbo41Fc0/2lQdjvNyGDSFM8wH14uT3HmRdgkz17sqCUj0LVgrjvi3QLQvCnhx9/chL5nuzv7n0iFdj9o8cPZj55ESjPHu4fnITWTe4bRM2HIL6@//DhrFV8QF4o08TXCstv4r7vwKIx3ddlucZG9XIM0OJfgXRdbtnDLe3uXeAMT1w8W1FgG9VitlQ6zZavoESV@2elAW4g98zBmrc/GnhbG1BGNmTPAOsXZdSPI8vQEg9297DhpTKVOLQF0qCEspXCVsuxYvlvfuv3zDV7DWQS3HS@pfEzlJYn0VFmvHIWr5f2JdRg1HIubDoe2uwNTTYcsIWO8EEnNLpWp@sz/8IJAkhNXWfw@9AH4pvRx1/u4PM0yO2aT29OcNzjZLVZVlJJjsttFfPFrfVcMV3cKm7ktUI@n9ZyaW2zuLkFskdWK2qFYn5LSxc3ttY3QFYC3/zWphQDmcFqZzIgoGqyDN8SgLUNvDZtG@@fc9RuVYrxyWn2JqEnWUwP7UMmmxBHxvt6PZ9O1qxZFTm3gcfeQGAFiDozWOzgYC97cCDL99GCy2l7WVluoSVfzGY378uyST57IM/lZNnhcYqoYEH2uSWbvb8ny0MOAPUfynIXLfsFHEXLsoWWvd2DA0ynjZYcxodgZ9yHW3qBZROC2WhZX6dhuCy/DsFBuF2e0AbldB8tmCb6HHCfPfCT5Y@D/GSzAOEpD8chfBKUdXdXlg@5ZXcXffao4Hme1c/QskuPLLtgASKU5Q4YOtgjyHITjEiKsmyAyRjr4IZX1KEKPBvb4ZgjCFEkyyMKrRtnMgwWhTsm88knn@hdv2V2@DN2@Rea3CH4WKPh/kHz44@bnU7THe/uf/wUffb2PtHb46Hb7DRFtGYDHgfigM9Zfzz7QB4PGw29N9fnM/CxZ3wa44aJeWvoryFP4ulgIv3GHvjsgc@8uX0ODZ4@BG3ic78P3/t6k3yCh3zoO2o25TISKuqgwJl4bDNnNvCCdF83XKeM9lFlhcUT8fS4VsjWy@TO@gmWvAQOhv7tBN16jgMskLYvx7VRJVuvjCqbOXE8LyGfjnJ5S06v9He0LZBP9B0tt5EalfCWDKcdZ3FF20lod9feJB6DKLK@UZJPd3YUuabVd3JasVTYfLE2lOVkCd8765ulNzDmisPACl/J2mZ9B4SeSZTNzZSeyZU2N3E8Vr4CjPjQKTWHvtloJBIXpn6WTGKOsasHQYyKy8ZUVKvcTozSowrPGBtD/FFFK3OdTCx7DVgL1QEO8YZhDrKTQAyMdrIlXBFJyNpWUYYsZDKJZBIZE7IS@L58Hizlhp@IYcrIH5WVFH5BuVYsJFU87dVw2g26pJW9jIac7LKQnuMRTVLPEOyjppkArySd4HgTewQSsKwmcBmujmMkjbjWL8YnJ7XNLUmqijHWE35rZFlYP/5kT4Vhl7ChgkH1AAVcx1X3kO1N@XDld4HTCXR46icm7o42Arc9rjhB3R/B8Bql5MAjUBSlClU96skn5UulgasoXzs5Ozn5QrmKgj2G8SbPCB4vK5OqEVTVgOoYrRbTK1Uw6ShOUi4BBckLQkejWq00Kn2zP/DHUOYg3me8r50AOvR4YcJjbxT9Eg@DCo9GJXs1Cf942Gf3eSA6MRpEa1TuA36zZRu1G5toXWWj2EiqtlBX4/3K/cthCUXSq7JZMV3XceUYHrPdsStD29Pb5hPTxROeh0errM1MPEtpdF@e7mPIPZStr5Sqy@ypfCR0pdpMTjtFrIi6xNdCjFzSCQVc@LuCIUriRbL8GmzuKku01PvJnY1yK3GfNZLgkn3ZftlmOVbYKNOFQAmEBByBMIcY0ZOV6mcAmMM9K5UgI4IkzgAmJrQKNWK1yEdPDqyrcqdSw9Bv8bWtyHJdUWpv61K1LFWBwZTHMb3iDZv8pu9sU8tlC@URuGmbG@Uua1aaL0ZltzKAkTkr96DaxXQEP3ah4xZ8QBLAefM28f5XvsGS20q@wh3LBOxtD4SJhtqojCY1tF6p5TYK6VxhA2cvCuvw09K59RzuKk7nslvpnAYyBcgaEB9@m2DfgB@EAZEjp@EcR6KXkBmT09lRVtXSmqmlE9mXVutlMn2Gk0wgGBLSkmnf2beBcsABCQjIlqzw1ZOp3Fov0XKYvq0QDQPTK1NB9XSXDax0F8E8NfUeD55U2PpaoreawDCrJ8PBfq1eKoGo@TX0SiivdwqpzWzqTTJZTqywZMUzXxOWkT8SFgYrQNFi6oZ5w34tuwLlhjaoXEFt@6vaZq5UG67WFA0KmH3b2Zarch2q64pJ8BddWQaxqwxuAR/kgtpE1Jq4DVDE7plQtdpWriyCSAPBmBNy4lQOTgkl4vHNXDyejJdxRnMF3AVjJxYch14hflfbkUHUk0vyVk4Gnj7h59eywOf8CpoUu5JwjMs2tqTYpXR1ebUd3ST5GRuPdRC@xXOXsU5qVWIZ2g2kNmJshUyKWqWp593KbufpblmE3t2TYiXc0jvZbslOuYoGJbMS2Rh522e7@oJ/T3FzH6QqkT6vGqvT7gHTIk3In@Optx0Wh2Lpbr@Wy63Xa7lN6NKBDwdBczmtvJrKsJhKezihOrxLiSOfdrRltlPVzKkky8SM@L6GYp7mRKFE72LU/NneZTDVUcLLKRJ6iTf2Wj357rHVuyyuK3xEDtzn6orF@Oby3LXN5ZBwsFn4s5e5PNST7QQOMAb3gd9DH5vPy5CBzMuB92WuuP7o8Mh@4B6YjO@zLW405GqMZWH8lWnEtRLttB0cb73YfFF88ejZ0bOjAyl2uvJ2xYHx272VbLZULBVZufzO/vRrbBBf34hDrZxWYqPKhjgwolWriradYztAzawEvUBbKyjZt1VOmlXyKOTA5/2v/GBjtF0Eew4E6RLgNp/KVavaWi4ZG7z/6g/wwPDl/ue7D1kcFbj8/Z/@OLf593/6r2iLSPyq7NHc4WYMQqJRK2zGLi8Hl5dX8HC/fKwe43na2EyCmW@90WLVTExssNE2tWTMU4RV28zHvLciSi6Lxw3Ad@@IO8iFPLSN2P5TK5/T7m1jjWhhjbDwb9v0tmJSrPjo5VvGwGJUW52OlSNTJsNK7xS2/U7ZZu9wGvudssJeVqq4WqZlMrSZmM@lrlWrVQTD4tVUZi3Ocnnwq12V6ylGc7EwlHuBA9rTqdnqUxucTG8N/0z0Jvua54E1sJlrrzzIJMtXNQaDwUzmNPn@V34zlyv8/Z/@@tvG28YXwKu3trYKWi72M8jSkvOqwWiOpoTw5CkawlEgW3C3sWrIUgwvvG4zHj4YE@IoEPU1cG1XaJPOHUuoNGoA@nQQwRMUbA1P3aVJGKcj@smyJIUSKwnbbsdIEwy2hurcoWFJl9Id9IJ@jlWAtUl3JqDAoY9qsoyG1xu6A5IbExRPq6fZXYgCKdxBxSordFpQ8EdFK7PM2vWoPMtcxxJJJqxveh7qVgP@Ld2BKA@BhulyOTbQ8cQphrRsYMgqBqF8kkerBmnXIe0ej9Ag1wSVngdIM547HskGYVy6g8fnSFqH7ptZ2xCgzJLSHUAAlCEhAFt1ts3Wk@zSSqXKE1VsV7glEvVw6MF5NgmjIbQWHuIMIpcxnMXVrQxdVEHGRA0bZtQxAMJh8KW2CowjMDrZUPyhI6u3BgWwSHVBgorG7t6d5KpSsVpJRiVC@KiJDtXHTfRmXUsAgAWDsI9aJTnN7FQKK/vONNkBxlOUXaA6hQyTQG08WIjWK0mC/1sTLVLkTFWRRxkLIOqLtwoDUAaREe28Dg3UpaflNpMszLwBeTcoU6SSJxxZno4@UkkzlsGzeCX9LBaoPgb@chId/wi6nT3QyKDPGqJSWtTWwJmBOKrI79BCPnXoB7HDWFAUq0eh25YLIwlaIAyU@yTWtSRGa4culA/iyrkNhjsS80n8UCwMjSpgdFSnItJZoVlv0kPnDRyb9K/QSXbcyEla8TyJa5vh2R7aFzppUuOp0DbHSI64ejqkfNKeZnMVcR6Pi4uR/NIEgZs0MzsqKRrKbbEEV3mIs5R2CC5JkSjDMH7UEcfNntmHLB2bJkMNIF4pk@mA6DFsksqPRxbQVffAgt7C9jLiVr/MhXVmZU5QoaritEGcFUdMYyitWKH@LaFXg9Tn9awzkw9rE1NnhD2WK6RBXEwDZic/QGwJp2zxHHAWvNM8FPw24bPJjcV0JO5KYpy8/l3XVhINrNG3XJOVizf3net2BL/0vJXEYNQbe4ECADqRCnY1ZLnQMvmpvzge@wuPp0pCU0GFTtGrOJc@SICkFZxbRSNIqOY5hFA0CfsYYJpGcKAWWzGU9g51ANT2oGWhjhzfLeFJ8wpqj0sY0PQEg7fZR2w9J5EuQdK9IFQlAAys@so0dPCDqFgOz29Bxah8RgL4CrTOfgv8YqgyipMfxg@oG82kL2pC3mxFgMNOh9KqMN4sAks@YsHWwbX/QdFXwLMAOZyTk5WEnAKwKTkpc9Bh/NnonNol4iUldh1SmiEEgWqAgqLCfd3jGkuFepuLiwuVdCwNXUs1PVS07eGNpJlBxwIR1cn4Zn8grkuy8NY8cSPoxKRw9fp4d@3OiK6M3bo75l9JauOZ79dDyzUT8bYXxz7wHHVCd/qkvgIVS3hENwcWqZs3ErQW7Qkyy9XTlwGZlZDMlGL8CoEwhmBG6XHaSAOwdNM4S7cvWmXhwS9bB@BQWWbgiOoP3cDS9wKTNWiHIRyfdlAH9mbvzHB6DooeMp94nSTNSxiEHAdWYR9YI4hkmxds13X1cYL8kxga6TQxJumGjaF3Jx8wQm/CLrmWMGtUG9enoo/C6NB3hSuwLiqvkC6XA@XK2dB/xP1H4D/i/qNJokGytVGdS17odIXFQeJGbVRBSAQzDsJccd1yEx@CDBIy0zgIDDmecruCn1Gh2AG@uQ3qsRIQBtAEqXRMoC7J2mnd9syLtXoq0wGalgkRUOMAulYnnF60QjNiv3feGzjelJONqpqg8xH5RiejK6iB0wqWMawgIgyOLws1@nT6Kp974f2@KDBAQHELPFEC2PUTVrIcatMlTyCcmjzBMc9YTWSmTkKW8BJuIBVx1HPERgHVI4DQPSwSZBN8WNByxOUJggk8d/EG6yCsQpchkFrgeD0OmJxpKpyllKmSIrlSlCCbgHaUSiuzRQn8oSpqM16RYl6J@o9mf@WDs9@GdjE/90SwvF8oS9GmYo5QBaopmgthlVUrkXqFHGTW9J7pQge1z8VQ0SlDMmuZYDTB08EicNW9iUjlG0leP3ReRbblUkgK40oFijiu8GbJ20WAUo7wMJonoo0DQhDxOQMBGNm50UwRbRSNNqpUOONgowXRLiKZHFEmRzwKDz1akMm6iAaDpFA5LFZPHXUCgkAlAzyN95ao/1Zmnn6OSo7ZK9TgA4OnIM0JzyEqEDSEkjTSmVGfm3otkukI05oBgIR4DUCL39dUkmYZnqaEtpBHcVQGPIrbBBlwXgEERiy4zLW0JUIio6EuyPVyivoBaLtyqibJGm4Uo78s/8npwDH4adcds9MhtWnHbHrm75fiWEfMRhpoRMjQshvIkHHAsktKa0AsuXBYYo7wDO6Z4K7vTLPnNDN9HbddZNzIDeDJYDxAiinvDRxf952NjRIfBFlEX89EcBa5MYWPAayO7cBQI6oH0uJ6K@04quc0nI5teWYa7xznIrhJuwO4CncpKvcKo@NJkpgQ5MNSBM0JCEXXRgNvmWs0Ep7ZaydLoZJVtKpIh/G4hONZMEXiAx8SQI8GCaf5yjT85M0wUUmqiHZiGWeJo4HwjEMiuwyYlQHyPPh2QVRhnjMZCZLuQhSNm36CrsTpOn2nA@IdaibF2DPgDyewMUP6YEB5STMdh6iliCpZag4JI60nRdTPPjgq@yyX0JNh/Nw0gClkpJk7i2PErDsnucbC5Hi0IL3jD8/vcTS/x8vzS6Pq2TzzoXaFe35Y0uuJCQQIOMnG@s3ZSAtF4NeyM5WV0BkFKB7h1lls0bamFuZ0F4LuiuBqG@gjHdo8Uk4kMv75Ivwvr8Ag@v5tq0/HSzePx8Bv@rh7LkFXOHjBsmECgh8mkfdcTy4k7Qe3TAvC4o0mBygrgLxKjMtGzVfQMAcwjPbkcMlEAL6B5nHb0jW6p71MFe45J0/ueZqd5RZX0YNGy@zpY7OVECHTEbhBiZ/CyIz41e0KjoyOmJ7DB3UJ6KSSUcXZiHQeqLSAZPT0eURt@rUwPIgVUg/NfFMODxfjD/2vsWacsqvw2WcQ@OPxGGnYpwsRBuPBmGsM7ZHq4YCP8v6H1yQe0b0ZIYAHseMhPUk2uYx9Pk2ERbpFjxCGVaeLTLrBgm7L6Q@u1@GHoejmkkLlRiJVglqe0mq@qMatZTUeoYqAJvlSz@1I8iaiuzXNRUiNA5uwsL0P60KuQcadDoaRiELkLktrzLGv8QR0o3k3e0Gv0pjDUMOYxOl8i8bVJF8kJRwCH8IXJ5A@hy8C7Jh@gxNUUDacoxJX4jDy6euDiNQiXEAaBygRLAZ3V1A2IqGkwAzBL6/CNI2FaRrX0jSm0gxbwHSSkUCSMZWkqAWsnmVV0DPb/gLujF44SIbPMrYNj@3oLk5LXMateMlKs/h5vAQMOW7GS/sJYMrxVrz0gAxevHRMhrN46TMwTNpW/G28FDQLDOCClQz30F2wcLQb8dJeInkl@Xi9SJCuGi@FdQphdriVMAKowHKD1IhLZrYjium7JnRsJFSmGVKMl8ZxEk24pOmXhX9@jwC/7wY8cc5yjQKzFNOmOo1Ij8HTgW4j0C87pyWXRG@@f3RAO4UmFzWAfwoGc9E4BB7E8Fh8mhnxjKEvrVDAFzKIfLM0P0dMm77N4xbZEakDhVIlT6dP2FNJHmglyL8GgevJ6UsiRPygvqZB8Aq8XT4x8qJ8XstOkBzlCNdYk3OyhUh9GV9SKKzrmRtQeO1Ha4jmrqcD4Z20QRBeSwQ2wtNBhqPFNkxs4AymiYR8cf@fFY1Ds2@8USL1zkQjriBa5gJvchYlQ8YQbfzJZcWJxMOsTbEg9Kxl67yVhf0C8WL0mvC6iKTKGx9kIcJzoIWbxpmJZPtAGCkcZzdp6isWdUNBXJ4kca5pNgmRVdQ1MtR9nno4eN1HDSQfNnwNYo5wUiWBACIxw1Q4f3U@QH53uPweCNQBEmYSmCdYz@9Kr4vXS3vZmZz3Jsler0D0TLMHybnCUZjCBOUwOohI5sto7ZqIj1s4uJDPEw2hz0j7AdrCMcENeJsdW3BYKCW459OOZzlwPMstRtR1iaR3rgZCi4opCTi84GFOJ0Vbnlde8HlVjD40ka33PriC3ekKjlYewqMCuDMo560cj3bi2takbZPyXnRBlqqVGGfktPwZVvPEEdg9LcWGy7DgcNR4@uDo8cOvQ6e7ubmZFH30eJI/bLU4qRr24xwy7VIO@4M5w5ZcGpXX4@I13aGM9zuvnNryNV7CmTUIA3htT0B@oo0nBS@L8POZtgvxeNgIRgWss0kz0Ke4Eoo6OnbZlsCrDwgx/cSaLoAE4i3gO02jtSTOyQJ14A2AjQZ1X40GbkZqNEQvhlUTrHAnfxZbyQw9l67K5aq1LySJzmizB0fs@Se7J@zkk3128GzvM/b1o2fs@e7jEzzT/OTZ/YeHewx@@4@P99lkRgEfvG4EB5SA1wemYfabeKVuNrvBCPKeMxhzvpPYS3L3Y73PPnEME9ejtj29f6/LLapt@lUeax@Go2Ocw7ToTpu@5fv8sj4DwJFw06IDbbjdn0HYJoxp@zjm7Tstq21BWAnHvgPL9IIDV6xnQQ0Cvw3OUqa5kIRXn9BWILr4ju4sxEvvIDwu0gAY3Ztcsmh5PILZUplAXPh8MAZP9p8@Oma7jx@wvaPHDw5PDo8eH7ODo6dgffL1w8cfAz4Pj0@eHt5/hl4U8NHRg8ODw71dcuAZyKoMT63TLYbLsqBicMKKcYZL3HRldmiLzjpDMJDg2YVOR/s8Fh/ayH0svWe9MVvxsoTXIvHjhLQmwMJLCZn5GpcygzVf2k8gP/PoYp/VLNum1KCxVKG9lUVzhW4PFazjwkN/zPCCJ7NMJ8gTZJ5cHEWbclqWyeQ93HOCc9/8oDm15QA0JLQCsBFUsAGlwui2gng8vU0gq5Ca0XNQARtPjW8KFBaMei/YOlKWCGNi7wsCxTMAhzbOB2nl0AHoHhxyIlnf5QHYeujAA7AN7oCi6CHuBWF5EWLoHw2RPbMCd3jVHxzQ@i/bDB3u6zSKLYo88XqjKtVZeGMKHrvv0X0TfJaHLpLSPcOyKIpH4fG@hl4vuM2xaQLJA08Ud2/hXjUIKQOzaeNSg9jGZg@pYYMvUAPu@9HbvscSlaTKTnCzj2lb/CKPTk@3@ZamyVYcoj1WRE0jFbFZ2wpvyKBTFQOHCBBvrZnORxjvgZAKzdvGg5j3r6Woiz2PdMtSsKXspgzcv5aBnwcMAFKmRjoG9VR0tBPBOG1BygnPAYrEedt30fBAzq2hYU5FCO7afGW9eZMUSE5PjZOCfYeUO6givJY0zdcs244LbZzYah/PqCAXNLrOwLd4HSamSzC5KQ1CY8cGqb2sVKdSo9tRZ1K0HTuSaBOoeEGqTSDK26RKFM8XyUP2FbT18Ko22keH2dGbeP3zZO0sjYtIFyZOv4AgzK@ZxN6Grg0W8qc04R3v6OrPYqX64P6p8u5lGq@Z4GyBX64WbCLkV4X2MS1oHrTORxsQXZS7REsL7irxhk2MLfbUCW6JrTwABuPArgXjunuNcujHtw9fd8fDJ7Pu5Pj2bYXHUpAzcY489LqJCXdLs1qQZJri1JnY6xHhnZBZ4PWJwCVNMEN@fQ/PmWAtlAEjNvIRuuR3@o4QwUKC0jWHbeAs4hYwUd0h/CSr0taJQJCkJxGtj8yLxP1KqprMTHaOsAg6EwGLTgeQ8ZKwyf4T6q@ugXuwHBzw79uDKy7NHe8ePgjag6XQPihvSmoxLN4tRWDdHuy7JWB55/ZzgYWypxcD5p3kdWghpYfEmV6Nhbtjl6f48lrdUdsDMNj34gxKCDSS2tCmJepAJWqCR0hGwUwEouOTB/tPnzKZj08gLvA9HDK0BBtE2Cv8ChW@e9ayidmpodAUDpZD4Slwmdq6FjzLGvNc5C1gFUIGSQt8hMxi@spS4nqiZyERgnbTE0MMMDedu8uAB3k1AfgKLwQF5hWbiGFhAaW5xYzxzsfyopu6Bd7SXDaO7smnHdO878arx9xxFFB084/ewZMi8@vvOZePS0E6XMAyXw@pwC2QpPH@XZUdQ8IDCKiq0zW4pFqCKsVN81zAjgW4wx1e2WkJ@xcnKCIkLoRzWTjC1oVwLLLG5ePVQMyhnYfYDei4pVN48h3K4BGweHLZjlZoctLpJaa7IBAy8VKse1GqgOj1q3J4k25i0k9WQoE82tZWKTe1IJd1nJ0VsMuLA32Ee5sLs@xhNingtkuTUv5hkuK9xFRKAc7nFibwBMiFfH79JtizpQiiK78obN6HzPJPvz@A8f0EpDf2aHofKPfwcTrwnxDAEtTxrfJBg5mJCKLOnD5lquzUGUXzB3nh80KQGdQvbHTxCrDpVJNsNJO3@dB5jxSFTkGulSHShMOC8lZzDftXy5NDhnxjeisfnh5vbBgI9whe/Sw8XBfRsRJxwjOk026m69oUjB9L6jt4fIxOIy09M0eH5viGVl4Y9KRltmgB2uKQEd9Wmw6mGCgRmlVU8cpAnNQrz87qKVo5WsKDw4f7bI3007WnpiBlV05GWM6KZS/LALFemo7AXoOO4n3kleAHeUgHIAFNdCgvQbhJ3pg3wggIyzW60UFs@xQsVZut9LZn6DYq/EjLdN/2XYhIk6/7RwfJeRPq2fJUfMicN7ATECstK6pMUcEN53ER0jQIXpvoHumnJLzSQGyQXHLBsJ7RitnClkSls9N@ul/bqqfXjIrMoM/V7b43dC9aZx2ne95mPTZ41RwZ4zevGctvsHXUK3mXq8XUChU8t5pgqE2kyLayRLAigzukePRUZkwlZYq4nswmw@/yCkuSgcbKJTwBMUOlbK0fUCGelPMr/VqhXrEr2XK/ZtfLeFbPT1X8lJZKoMNd6DyBtfAF@Zpfx670Z9HZVtM@Z@6wOYZRUnj2g9HZD@zfcYZL7Nmm@XLaZizdwc1qeIZEtc2LRHh9OlKmhPKPdIcO8Wh4DJymi3G2pWVBDgD7aRBWvRG9x0npTlYdDnyHfERCCpIQe2u9le4Ep46yNGEAQWpWPcjONsGZhEngug93HfPd0IrGpTENjzomIyBqGJO4nXwqy3gEEDMqjl7V6pKnmrrRxUzgNZlvKRrb3qZLM4GkPJUm6XCnhu7SwYdsHY24vgGfAS0mYBIkmHt0fEOC4qNdQwN3oSkon8670EZ3iQRB9MFt3OySjiNR/G1AAEf8HS5SqWIGUwhWICfyo340d4Cq5qbH9biKgKcgeaXcwcIibJ5eZQKcdnwTjjBZgSZwv3OB6OS4gkeUQNHIdq0YYfgkD04ooWVoYfMQl1Sl5FXFT28SLRGJpgTRgsARVNy5ERs4kQWjn0cmNJ8x2zN7Pcg0x8WdCTrQSMdxRfqpMH2vhmnWw8xzf@WavzLlr3J/nqlJKBX670mgUjSQHLuchLti8iRY@lpaFUayiQo1baggcUzClpeF9VTfaViTwNWwKjlVhh7bUx5KxOfFnNrnPitTcUICD/1r3F/Qd07UfJjLqbD3ptPHryQqyKS9sWIryQyVqrbV2@GdU@iDZCYDNhnj0bG@iex4oxRHJgU7AQENp/Gp2VYrEygpLeA41Gbk6vY9WRXCxE5iNhv80OG1hjWnjUSwRGmmCHEjOl8I6ZD3SgQEwURCY0HLrQaRxyLyOAIWQ60EyfJDi9caOBRttolX8BjjW3wFjX06c0G42HzPOzznI154fhh5GkHEdFfk@Wia5iZ47IM7ikIt6UUmaY9nIc5nEo8jk7xhmiY/Mt3GWe6VkE9EGUXAKa7hPfQRmJ4E0ALyXVSF6Hkl/SyzJn2sgwg96JkjtoujCJ1OU0lT59FR@6qHSpFIP4s3HAx6uKhIgt0FnXgWijtyeVxNmUCMLKOp0iFu3OHh02gS58chksqOEPIF7v@YeHjDDl7ejes2qAsJWCtOqFi@Ku3aYz5fAW1mPcdPhZts6PFFURjMd6KZ4DXHWw9i2hvohqlKIIt5IOVIvKht3r7FdDkeC0G1XNCllSTpa0PLONv7GJdrN7XsuhZB2blY7c2q6xuTg1KApMAjlwVxNa9tSFJk6dfgS78KAkyzh9jRfw60aZ7jFdHSLvQYFNAD4dQz3XOzpUrSUzNc40W4SMq48IjHpp2ha/C5G5Ct8GppPO3rpflqF1AYfrF/5qvBBi2FpSVck5osJkNVn1stRGBwoKTt4OIvrUfgqX6OD4zUN31AylqSTWeJlpZFXkh2@X/be7bttpHkns2vaIO2CEi8W1dT0AwlUWNOZMsrUr5E0lIgCVKcoQguAVmkPco5yUN@IB@QT8lDPiUfktSlu9GgKEtzyc7snp1zxgKBvlRXV1dXVVdVX6GdCbCBaUmMoweNhlEQDTowM2SoSg2hKT7liDsbdecggf46Qw@DfPOLAMDolxgDCgB1UvQ1GFLyTPxnwSDkwNQRuqdmpgDcL6C1AsvdnwyA@8YIplmhagbsMMHNV/WGaBwdNN9Xj2sCnt8eH72r79f2xe5HOsLGc3BKByteHR0Cd9GH5XwofgQvrGoDalr0IVV981HUPrw9rjUa4uhY1F@/PaxDa9D8cfVNs15rZEX9zd7hyT4drkML4s1RUxzWX9ebUKx5lKVeVbVUXE8cHYjXteO9V/Czuls/rDc/Uo8H9eYb7AwP7avibfW4Wd87Oawei7cnx2@PGjWBA0vt1xt7h9X669p@HvqHPkXtXe1NUzReVQ8P5wZ69P5N7ViQD4Axyt0aQFndBVUVe6Jx7tePa3tNHFD8tAfIAwAPs6LxtrZXx4fahxoMp3r8MSsbbdT@dAKF4KPYr76ufgeDS9kPYAXmZe/kuPYagQZMNE52G81686RZE98dHe0Trhu143f1vVqjIlKHRw1C2EmjlhV4RRV1DW0AtuA7PO@eNOqEt/qbJuwZJ2/RncGBSX4PiAEoq1B1nxCMXg44WkDS0fFHbBXxQBOQFe9f1eD9MeKUsFVFLKDDxF7TLAYdAhKb5jDFm9p3h/Xvam/2avj5CJt5X2/UHJiwegML1NHf4iOQDnR6QqPGeQK4@BGINaUoN0vTKeoHorr/ro6Qy9JAAY26pBZC294riXNYy4WUYSwZBGgb8K5MA0rv7qtPPiZxvGt5WWyL0QmO9o72a7Ajy/RRVvzhBHadzbnMR@Y32Gn0R/iZyDDT9dvX/dZg1AswVlRXYwPHVdjP4g0cDqjn4iz1lUtYpB2FKqTTrda7agsU3Uar5WQfUzMBxkM1pJX7a6UcOUbMCo@aNxp4Xr5kvG8nELWzJM8xyQ8PzxewJGN/iT3bvCvfEYVC15fVMAgfG1YmopBPRS7xpARYI8Uy4t0TcZdkgaDfA0kOVNFWzec7LTSDouMjFQpC@Gf0U/yDNwfjBXBnNmsVCqjEEhiDz77qhjuh1Ab0j8wsMOhRl/nQ93/s20WzO9T58/0g6NqOo@pQ2Qj0wL7tPFC97ffnqufm6xOwdKosk8mHSu8mEUYfL0uUCTkv@QmNzMZ/WhH9cRQ0nLsBjaLUFdmipXHSXuLq6HCUFTJFBUZP0CSjzPe6@qH@HrW5Ynm1Mvf@lX7PawvdATENLWx4p1TvnP68OucCsMAopwagZCAzXRQKRh3lTqIL30DBSyxE2fZpr770aV8HlIAge@0NzT5xN54Mpib0wIe/O66@3j05OADWidCubq5trFdSOkvWhyz//Yj9UHJUShI2hn0c5DT6ZKySPRB8aKUYGbVj8icCLhSwIOYsV5NGLzFfg3bLSDoqISPD4YZ4EcsIPfAsH/FgCUqk8TSl6HXhypQEYCeG6uBorrwpifgeyEpEA9JXZTijWZviP9i2Xv5qiesBSQKSJEYpaYFyQbsgvmcdKE9QUm4ozw4WyVuKjjnrmsYBmbrIPRaDZ@mXpG1jFkP2VMT1StNONQGIp/NQCOU2MeKV/ZbyhUhDLyX7gjcfJL3B40eZj46y03lhVI0agMYDXRPt0bHRWQ76VLZ8vuPCFC0t6Z62BVrzHQkUrT1pNtYJPozVQKCco8@gK@Yaruh8IPNdkoPrtxlHfGFKxSQc2E5FUqz8DZS7aDiylYrKAyJ/q@wSgtvSyUoYaze6j5Qq8lHno1DoTKDpV@GD2v8dcbKg/W3QOKH1GFtGzr5HYZJaZVyB@kpIGdyoAwXjFCPGpvnqY9zMrTkxl3pg8pRmyuEzgAI5OzP14iNlKezZCxCARI6GDXP9ao@zSw9Up28tR1bH85BR52psC7lXqK3iTru59fMsiV1ZdYaCPxzhsK3J6PAQqopvWXFr06oHlWlOlRfPQ4ubc1Qej8IyGUD0gicqvWSn1HnKKspVpviATJlkbDhdnfkIxNLbe0/nloWR0TLB@@UJl0IUNL2D8NwdJ6UwDwR73yYTJHLK9CYlrcMs2qgm4@YjM8y1yc9y6GM7z7tkDMELZqMb3CCG3Dpl1otbE/Zz8gPBTmKnwjgtILJbJw@opW31RkNPlkmkUA39yYhz0fts1VIl8py/Q0JoRsPnxWtvBiAPHzdsJrHCciPIomsidsZmCVkfL9PtBMEEREcPxw0wZgczJy/eS6ODPwqvJzLdIOxng4m0SCihH7pBsYm1d9pmOO05gRYOIgxG6OaJPmhIVz46gHL2kWluXdhAvIpGd5TRcTBdKQl7O/6yDTihLKKExG2xLn76iUsxQmWGT58wOAi1ckEumdQPnjvo5XcTTH7EvR9FoFHX7@pEokaTZAvkSaqPKCVjJ@Khj4OQLBowFWgB0ZgosSFN@6HCHr0hyUm6LVlxMktMNUoj@fn9aCJVzlDQUUy4sncgvvUcTCZiqSwzeercnqXyGoGySOG6vVcZo@SeyeNpYZ2NNEt5yUKE@1yJjvjEfFM/fcQnaeR3n4e4euANnmVLERQBRpkVz0/v8jmCDxPzvR/4k65pEwVJpuuN0fxGqk8wIlpUpkOZvq/jRaE/Aw2gUxhMC9RGy/4@uBy19oKh1x8EAw/0NMx/PmWOh48zesQJ60@Cm5CuzaEPXaNQdxY/c/oYTqeGv/W5ZMVIsRVG/tg23RGiyax6yVkgyHKOPn5C71dE3@P5XGe6zupaXCmVDC8ld7uSU7m37ovSosp8co8NSAa3M@cpwSGiEcUdGbGllTsF2l8rYMDYFjnhOfc45CUg3gIU0TFMAmIFzB33A3MQqJndC/Fpd5rtUi7BCeZR8vd9vHgmtOl11sPLVoGLfIMeAS9FabNoVOVTlCnmE8SH2f3oLm/8ztADAL8C/NKLRdSyiBCIxfVUMqWQ9RWZFBRgIe@/AfFo4sTAxQZ92IWGiUZb0/lWk59n92GDPHxAKJLp8u5QJa5IGxQfvHDNbgHLac0c3FQyIuNQWg4UQaqRXbyfYP2H3GNp8eMhLlvOkDHtyZZtA@j7UNUBLOE1mnPesybInAL54RVTLj921uYQ6C7yKDOud7AtJblQgMmA91c81gomwIytOexJV49MGAXjzCOxdy/vWJhhbRGuO47zoJ8vE5sLm@Vyl1DrzvBxVknNwzNHNEmMkUcZ0BCqr/SsyXweiVO3hevNbc0ewMN9OIv9o/Smoue7y2sfN8VP6LCrNhq9pAh2TDZa0e9PWzDw1v0cRLbJ6lWLOEYLWUZrxo9GU3No0lh6PIaI@iTsc/joAuaw3y7gzpyfe5E67wynUpeqT4lklYhPzLOOMZnAl8Y9dL7ALHAs4WompQXOaXZGR3mlXBuTBeMHbhClYj8X26HYghtP1hwdUTL/nt1Cb6ESciJ42jE9HHSOfo0wSqIvjTvS46E1y5XOK9zSVLcEWgWV@lpLKpwcfp62ptTKHVTAEl@ACj2iO7zp8vGj@rVjgXLQAtemz9KRt5jFwThiBaCBf8xPrSnKwHFXsmZiRSUXQotYA6wF0FL6Q5/VVZT@BhOmePRukMsIFAh@beOfFVkDs2@vFzW2scq0O8MijkQ3rzZH5Ha4SkxQ/BvRL5cii7qkuEIDPkMM9d0StIDpSQl6PBSgzDom5SUAlXMEFd0SLkt4SdlNY3/OBd8RqbLA6ppRorioxJbZRm5hIyBYLC4TAwIyy@IicSuw0S2ExSixsXg8cQkQiBXtM8ZhKuSsJHGoZ44RCI8EreYopyWRLUoKpo@ra07io6Zv@rpVNL4W578CfjSEp7nS/NfNYuJrottyOVk1URPw4Zi9Jj4CKhwTYM0Vft1/FHlipi7XPqGGkpGQMqQf9ghVqRvU2/I/hGKbYq6VjKHaMwO/lfrV4htREsnVv55IXcg0/ZVfP1jlmKoAkZn9KeucCmWxWR8kgdXCnR5HhYquyqOn0w8olTboiXfNg4NEUtf2TPkZXfmTtWKxiDTcNnPYKxdqtCQNgkKydKF3PRwWxjffT961C8T68bL6YRi8VAq0DzMCayLMB5M@3@OAMEBRLJ2TYaqo6l/3euaFCXhAiXMHs8YlZa4DQfvPQPu8vGuS/YealPvrBQ4Qx3ch9OK78VjOlK2oUyiojR7Bnyx1eAbowRc9dMPWB1XUGPJl5cwE25bj7nzBDQTvIaHJoizEzpfYO9l65Q@HQVa8DybDLuYBeHI7X@HgwKxQ5CJ4wEixu9chZZvNCv/TYGhEDWMRk9SxObUvqVshVHp3THF/7Pdr07Ftnf7Zgl0FhryCw1zBNNNZYfUtR@Z8f0SzTIcA9qNKX3lju0N4mi8MO71cwPETQPSilF2o@iSKOGQSkzh7uDQidTG4eUrFAEN3SBRQKelpemkk9xTXyLXOpqUe4rDIbUiYMKPK42pgINnvxxU/Rb3e45giZfPnif2rM0Q6AqAVKJcf4BOTYf9TDpb1wVy6EJZv8M6Nu3wHK7SwQir1vOP@5cauVqvi2XhlRVSru/CQy4nqblXs44vdXbEPv3fx95JbXlurMM/dd77Ay1318lbsQhtk4FzpXE724Sd8czEqDJ21cYqfFdxn2cqzlru9UwkLp9VdDNqHp//513//n3/7j0JV/vhP/LFLP07/rAvl8/nCs86XZ0u3Ffx9un@eedY@fTY@z/QrSGXI7k8moTf0DO/RfCf1QIRUdzho3xc1pb1nBiG5aqK7pA3/uC5oYD/9xE9nUfw4iR8xJ2pc3RuOLz2qLqiFHTdTzSwtwdO2m/nnDNlO5HtPv/8M74WDvJySJhBq8d4fUW3s1etm2nHk@iS993zMkYMXW8p8OfLg6iKtbgHMnYp8XpznxIUGD908WlwwCSKrmQzMv0gg1ejIJ4fOrqXagIfSZPpmczwfTF2FfZLvlOmcLz/zpKbyvPuSz9CojRVgeFi@wr7qMu4Vhw/g4rGXmzstra@d59LpdEpfiNbqEJuj3sbUl74gSx2hU34GDsMaw5KBsdMFdS7iAhpEZKTTdF3WUoevdbNHqFqTxsQKdzpjyPNob6KBpDSbYws3J1NAGQsVPrqCTITXFIWBssHssWd4AACF120T4xJ8M3I49juD3ky7POCNFHHvsFdiyNyy6N2JmBPWpG3JcT3txQ0CQlAKoFw92Oh8g4y8AMoOiNvxGNVvEDfuEtWFTP4tVmmCtUPQOBjO@kPozCZXqvAGuBNg3pGTNRypUDrsgWu2fZB6fLmiecJiX16Eu@2jKWLUwRMyvB9qiDm5WODj41/KRgnrASUceT9cD0NB7OGIHYiCHjzCho9RdHyERWS4gluqJChUalE5VvfLST6wPHYcMeaSiFX4HR@@E3mQCZL0YXnRnUwTwqcxY0fWxLfbktLGeLUfKtIyN6gjV5JFa0WfvoFUeYVnlXhOCUjBknm6SwxYw0xcDEcXevx8uhnidYR5S3XJ3ZTZPwE4lu5GhctTdxwLYLFxlW4ewxNOeTl2EIaDNiALhiiniVIgcvDABFo9y6S4M0kteByICMZXy2O9oszxKVLyp2OKz2d4n6Bpd6SoIFEQD0jxTMzHszvMcRBIlge/RsEoRyy37UeDDjtQcu9PFS8e47k4HVMSYPd3BMqDh@PUE0w9nKnsQvK4mKY6bofwhMEKuP4vtejtEc6kmVeyaBk4AgBp4tCzcxYjKW5RUwI1kESKhJH8vyUGnyQIc@j3B1GiTlZmYGC3cx7FrUI9LvILBNjE7hxmMVBCnTRrlnAh8a1cM5Dxqm/AaDcdGfy8iPbUYHBX44sndU0eEsXTbd6lD82PFDgm1LCCAX24fLPJGaLNFfc6SiKHqTy7SVIV8Sx8tQdqXILI/GKZAnyoAckt5nGSOwVslOewAex0bhnEXLiYaN4gYCRucycnHjWHXp4uFgnuMG9FLwpSJILblA7p@fL/3W9iKtsTjE@GxQelkA5gj44dTnQejfkmF67AG18J6jI5HrDGyTVmpGNHFrmjYAqbAS9So1MNx1xXauhyhnMkKY0pPwr8PM2YczlXVY03rn2erJ3LcEjXFxXYZRuSztiR8V7y6xPezGE3Ve1yxBYdvdGvWxVaJiOztMOEmh2JctpevR6iBx1i6I4lPTm3i0hD6fCKy6sxS8kChMtE49QWHdHIcqZP0AIksa9C9ToK6tFvL9NTbml51qdf0nWrIBd4IAZLEcFzCvIJHtH72Pmt1ALkAwNgBOy/5oU@PKdSLHlIDdN6HfZ3g6ldzJ5ZZ1a2tL7lWKQnazks3QlBM0p3fM6Whlc2St2TsjKSXfuTzyx80h50u/5I5WKFqrI3/aklmz1Fc/4Xze5CvuHWIibuWwYvD3MwifRC4pqexxOvf@XR45ugOfFmddiE6OfRiOezge0dw2aEdzLRl2Neo9UuiBrWLerJMU08aojkFeWB5NOJSDTgTHyGuLAAAf4dBHCfevxhcrAGGszxs@1CS8@0b8KkXrCEErIT9QUfnFyk@MLfK7yRtsXvgDZt40Zg@Uif5q6pljICflAOwsZbrsGi/hBPevxR4hxCpQ6WhMfXRnOtrBgCgRaVyvX1oQTsD32hoQ8vpGITdS5bV9fDaCBHdmdYalxYaf7uY1In1XXV99x/TCbDedwZ48B2TwewSmNdhhhVjAWphKlWDP1RoZvGT2bHWGiQqgqn/SivEn0UbytfmRuW7neUqoFZOYwDG6Wc4jhThroBtSupeJ8VetRPE8oHwgFIQTCWx3TxNLHmW3OOcYYxbwgxEz25fw2d/W9ZyeU3dNoQY0nppdI9k3lYrOtTVEFWFOUhtqHVAqXwzePBlS81W6lOGMqrcWscJ9P83RXWBzS3hPRnoEp5bZuyy9PEQksIh8pf00CnFmJoZzZngcZqCiOmJEEsZywTIzCeZUu3HJW@kG2wUgIlGeZ5IVtJTHqkC9gbNHFn88xqMeLOJ0dJb1oCoqJAU13FVOXuFm9s0t8XrXrxDqZgTcqUpsgu4g00llkXKOGaDB5ElH8XUaVfhiiGaxGe@MtvhqYkApJYuk2lFpGvZh3SNctc6zqC6A5fIsQ91YLwXBsLBN32EJMGxoDNNwcTqCT7LSUML4tqH9hiUhZmx3AvfsdaDyuQ4VzIuDbEcRjC9QST6qZBukrB/5jgGLjUFRp0EhYQEFkLKV2I4sMQG4RvbY2QKQtEIe2kpM9QIc3XBJU2Sg518oieMAL3V4j3zAbxKKZ3J/gNNxQSOZZFSwYQPrz70V53j1k6Mb6FJmngyLFRmtnz8niMQQUPWakLaZnKwhbQvHDELzRQk62kzHsQ2nkK6dQTAIElDcypB51R7RVp4A19GIbOyMnm3NgNi/VDZej@I9m/FY6Vr4KkAC0gFJV0gPIZXQHNEywlBApkpQWaeR5mANU6dmZhL7GoRuIioTZByWoHL8mteqFBSM8K7dKhiG9QnUSGVXGh1VRZiER6YTVhY4pRtGbQ0ZHfQUO4tlKFjmEPlmaHArQtb@QGsDhQUjeZYFfmcJaWhISNTNZzMsZCRT@BKIYjgYyzkYy3mCNdYEL4khAvtxRYJlrqGy@0P3ABWSJenUuLBRFkr7EcEltoCjHer0ca84uxQ1W/hh8Khgjm4o0IJ8RRde6XGJrUz0XoPD4fIFIy6P3tUOnPmonHkqq8t/s@WuS9eKPEe7G598zCAlobcPfBv4MOx/lSYGm8/4hlM/j6Ce@/ZKaAf5hAKV4h0kkEgNuHkSPvGn8S63X5MGrxtema/aIeJ13uul3YjoHZUkBTFvTEiHyQhIFn5WBLCQZ@1oaplHTuXrJCUDERlHnNTNaO9TJBipmh/qqsBISpngzjfgLNkXsRRXLi0VXQ4bwAsEHh9x5lBSC9tsRqESpEXPEUf8qYyic9TlPYkyuZRyCWW7JbOQYJDw2CZazdiRc9SsSKj@TYYV@MMEkUSFnzdBjmU6L@80Wyx8hly4@Wy9LLZNNejsWz5fQYZIsXv7CNv66cFhtooR1LQ27hQiUDPqkcgGKYoCF6GMfGfMm1zCO3Xy72/UN8@aNuDMt/ePFlWaO/kxRilmMhprNQiIkLyFodNLxRPV2e2AMs2xFpyMtS7OH@gmR/sG5Uf8HC/vgmdhGXk5UD6hZfL@g2uglkDU2oskOyPy7sCHktr@kLS67tC2HfXdA83/E2/OIf2/Df9zZc0LjAbKMP7DTG1P9j7v8e5h7zVw43i5vF1m927qvfWSZhWXPnrUJYT0Vp55uNs@l@8Wy6tXr0l3SU3ikX3k/gb5T@S3p9M82P8AC/Xqhfn9I76W0stn6bnhVc14VH2Ur1AFrZ@V63iaVm2/DPzppqd32W3sm5VP2n9M46PJTKZYDkbFrbOptuFvF/q/JHEj/M0xUtfNzX6phy2sgNgc8CpYs8qeVBGDe5Z@wOdSQBpY4nDaS480OjOQIYnWem5c2ilFWAgDj5wydf3r@l0mZI@ZHyx0SU0YQjLlTaB@mrx5VgBeguHPhDXdBuL0WvOOGEyjWBUkIMtLh4nl/Ho@sLmYNCA6DzTZCYya7coF7Y1DGmN8O/O8VvLJ2P4qWVSIKRPNuUu@Km3BX/Ny3Gs@gyGJUXZLVPiz2YrsgXP4QMSzgajMd@xBJ/3x/5E0plAsNBQQev2evgpYTDwY/s/vdSNS461FDrh7DFsTncUH48E9azb2FlDa5IK/oMq1I94/nY@qr6BYwbL2zDOBkVXdMfRJfXbbqQoDmZ1aMjykRRwKTmEWelKIAs1y5ceeg4QGn8QyAxKAHsYHI9KtDFbiCwYawM5t6/8n4E0PAyWRhatwXF0Nj/o003t4b@mEJcpr2eRdck@cNuwx97E48z1qHX/LXX9@uYiQcmI7y0UHlKizcUXBOZqYm1skQYBzlc3oeV4@xhxPvDjAr/JNQKgeHGdF2PhXHqkgkR77byFDUBtSwOLaArwntBEMXlOWpcV6CfyRqUjw0miUND8HAwHhFwcxz/igJiRQj5guCIf8pO4xfUEUEzEQO8RgNH5Y@ur4h29LW2p6WX5zJnnVsyrhcnj9fNl/JKectChOI0SWNzaRO/XLPvJZ1LpmTqAD0OEKwZEijIE3JNp4VXoCmEYdD@gRItIVeCBYn0l1ff5LInN3p4RGP3yO97xCtu2piMB952ByEVwJqF/meQ3RlF2QSptq/7YZ7XAgVWDMLw2l/b2FwlgGjHV0W7QSdRtFyAlifeZFYg4C6jq6EexVZ0KYb@J38ovVcIbErny4uS6AxvNPOuh@TWsu4Q6QAqEyMFLNhbWX63Xzs4rDZr@1kQU9aweEhhSbqsbSCXP6/Q994QMzUwGWEVXr759voqE7kdZjPfokWOQf/WRPuKCbBqIAzzuAcMxnbGpWrSz4IbFmNU20f9rD4Op1RDKms0LjcE5ZqumrAUctXKT6cxpCvEvtJIgonEBlAHB6YitydDYDx3Ct3LKwADkru1IqDIIfJPpFxr@2kup9fUS3rKAWPN5XbYyGLtDQegeGaOr0cJbpuhteOJDDA5PP5n1vY0Q3whb1XEpYt6fKXjFis6bu@Tfe180VdS9xAKmxHXDHZnav7saxmZZgFCHPJyViGT//1fGadyGyfRGdqRg1cviM@uyhydZ6Ze47tq7UzYgcmKoNrnfORPoz3O9OlGFV2hHXRneUqu1d0Drbprfzb7GNvOF9irV1Y6rvvC@QJdTsaYAXQMzNBvQotOBd/1Eu90iFjh7GyEF1AvY@jeh9eHr2DK0U/MD6PTP58vPytkMxnHqeAQPJfi@/aPXr9FK//EyZO1/2ASXEm8TDzdSR5m@yo8LZ4T9FkLh1bAVQics@9HcvTh7qzp9d@AtGRnPEABuiVRYBxMymDbk/FlFfRNQpkLL2cxceRaycm1nC99l0pdTvxehW0Vt6H7ye47lQj@XJpdrEEXbrlMrUdQyUWvpjmsD0awW79qvj50M9uewFbdBasis9LWxAGEQgRj46sqXkeVIB3gKkRVEUfrEcHAfysZayc5lu2Ct5Op3N7eC88h59MF4ScTE3DXvs5Kipu4d6e0MompYDb2XXzBW9t3taaVhbqYggVfjnB7mxHT4iBWV/XB5IacgrbAWQPLuO7q0hK9wyrXoeuWi0UHM6LcQmsh3h8PzfLCmlRuJ57btTUivfFgwW1J5Xy5wIEsYaG0Xi6ubXwTTGCLcPFC@qUQWIiLWsunQTRbAtnQd9XNS0sgJ8Nu6j5dXd48Guz@6cNWY33f7rS/L1lZ64eQ3PYnYxOAiXeTZ7EIeOxE5tolIDByseMVxt6PQWG1W@yA5Fna6Poba/5m8cVmZ81/sdXe2trq9FY3292tDW9jrdMuYLJ3qpK/GoxASrKY/LHb3uO6vU8w2ywXt3q9Uml9o7u21dsqF1@8WG1vrnWLq6u9zZL34sV6t7zZ3mp/XWqL4UkBg1V8F/eOeQ78/H7hLnWHt8vazv8B)

We already have Befunge-98 answer ([#11](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102417)), it uses FBBI interpreter.

FBBI and PyFunge are separated with `01-2/`, which pushes `0` in FBBI (`-1/2` in C) or `-1` in PyFunge (`-1//2` in Python):

```
@,,,"284_"># 01-2/_'1:,,@_
```

Second `_` is horizontal if; first and last `_` are for DOBELA.

Answer (score 3):

## 291. [Idris 2](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2), 13600 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                         @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
  
#ceppp         ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa



















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu1&&1&Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在5"" 16 ""61*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]putsR 8ogrFloat4*  
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
.exit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";   print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQdBgACbzSbv5dzuZg/Jvn1nQDS6ABSAugSq0KgCCTTJjplZe6yR5LU8O6sYjXZ1R7PWWrI2YuUNrzXySrsR0tcNxX7SD2g9HA6FQ/MPxueczCoUQABkj6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4YbvfnP4/gw547vUmn53jMM12PtYbWhTlU2aMJe2hYbk7PSBKG2h12Rn3T9tyiFGEaY65nDD3WM@zOyOiYLAKuOpva21bPM4dJ5poma5g95xL8M4zZ5iU7tJtWCyAxzzk3beutOQS/LGOPzd51/9pjTaffN@yWywZDy/bIN8fYcwMs7VHznBkN1xsaTc9ybPDKM/bC7hn9RstgFHwwNHmkTQagmucUZ9anwNhTZ@iakILTNF3XQcctcDSGlvNk99knc@G1NPvEAKQGPXM8l7ymsZeWOWzNx9DZ56cHB/OuGfaZ4tjs4DZKWpbtjjzn0JuHn2O7HdM2mK5uqfq8Zx6I6Zm9QrqQnvECvwNrCKVpiFIrTkvGHvUb5hCIL4rw0vK6KkQ4dTjBmWP3JswcAzDAsQ3BTI9ZWFosl05jSPg/MZuO3ZqCBycT4ABcsz/wJkxhtiN4ALycIXMHRtNUWmbP6lue2WI9C7Bz2gIbl0GBs3NzcukMoeAVzoqEiDswm1bbwigiB66EzPbYbIw6zBl5gxGg57KW5RqNHgRrTFjLbBujnpdkDfAD4pH7Zde0BUqW3cF8vJy6IAQbqgDHfl0D2li9HgN0zhEdTNpl2@hxie4YtGESlmYLQe1PyQWQjJ7r53424ZlkMN7zodMZGn1g1JZJNPj88Dlzm84QbPDDsLwWrALTNDy2vc2i@88eR1klIKM6bEgBScvsijEW8T3ZhdEbmS7rGxNI2/agcjGHys@PIUFwFl2LFlk0k2F6mmWzLAuVrcD0XJpBldgCA9RaPaPBL8/0AstqwPe5aBLTaQ@NjtUzOZSO02sjoE3kWD3HdHins9Ek921SGpssU2D5TbaZY5vw3mJbOiSCELNM28rBLw8/gLAFGGjwy2R5SgFbIDtBFtgeaxt9qzfh0AcDBN9kOY1tAkRAUwPIeqGAsWefMCyvC0TtGhcATulZ5ygqzEBaYEml4JPa2EiRuEK5yJNzu2avhykCkYA8uQLbhBTzkOEspAo01Au6n/FOl7JOOG2m4Qf4bUJuC0DaNFApjWTahB/YQQTpIGt0ECw6yApdA3cdzBmECuHy4JeHcsoHZNVbRFeQrBBXQ0KiMNEw/xCNQbFlsgwKLgtFm8GizWUY4AkIbOYZyJOCxgpZVthkhQLbSjMguwbIYLlrIMc0QEJDYFCcGpSnBohowCgaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFMtDz@IB4UugZJapCmrm9N2Qpw03OQyVyG@E3PQ9Fvgh8QSwdcdeAUHbDVC@CPcQtAuAKy46ZPCKM36BpICygBZGJgMyBIDnAi2BAezPpmhrMThW6YntWUbiSoUbz1C0sbX3Jg7QdJwgyGjScw35R7YoH0i4MwmhVUI9fsAReB/GgaYEaWhZqOUsOHY3kqylhookznAhtRqvozybgkHhpDbEFBVrXM4ZBhWGho3SQJEnfUcM03I2xnp3i1QTKZIFTbhtULEKBqY3jUBsA36kJ6k1m020OnT3Wrj4Ki5ziDJSIXxNIlAvrUuTSnqE@lljEY9ECWg7sJhBgZPUDm0iBdgFSFcKocIYiE8ZpdCwBSUiBTraHZJNqLrEPsDEjfWRSLTK88yCCUR6EmIcMGDghUF@PYo16vCE2d2WSZSqplXqTQhTcbs80F4uA3JNAWChANA9pxakgRiwDSA12lJurUL1nX6c9mjYuXwyDrXQvFf@/SmEDptUGymGOjD9oGwybdhka7DxzDSxBLwuWNziFrOXbUC6BcDqFphUwHOQGQPaKJZ/VN0MUciIIlniWkUbgRZo0JsDJRK6uSKsYxmSOUKs0TijtkQw68skCj1ho1kWqYtmUTB0Fj4FJLVQG4XOFU0QBVbmgaLR4MNQvEKKQbQUtnAtGFGtAkQKidmLYLmo6rMgtVQmD4jtMGHqPmGdQMiDpNp0l5x5wHTmO1qUpEaeSb/nmPWaw5GDBwB90E0DpIF6B9db602Fvw7HVd1muOhsMJGw@gAKw@hPKaTrsNTPvWHHQBBOu3WHPShFppeFLLIeHTHMzlNrCtmxDGNiHHe8@/wTomEBoa4jYgSUw@xX0wIOyJCobNG2nbACIh9s3BhCgCYIIYbcdR0b3lmC6xBygxQWXHxFyzQ5UBalZ7Kn76qHQAX4IiYAO3gqwRFQrhY4LSwsxgUqLcPzFtqCxN4EOo5lByqIbusjao/KE2GnU6o9k0B57gDIcEmGWH9JijA9RjyFURwFS3K60/BBVsBgMJgko@04Qab@Oc5Crq96ReGShdRb8CmnPbDDRXxmVJb3IreQhxMZe6/BrDzGDwWl6Cw4AqASp1JBZGHgoPlIdWs4vSz0P5QgoG1K/h6Hb2wS2c/LDPlHaQNmKjgaCR1FTghHgsh6HAr3cbkDroIazKjAMGnXG4A7Th9hdAdgIke62wq5oyVBCDdwHtO7azACoQM4CLQWZ9qCyIGU9QYBi9gBmpurgzZYQietrlxaYLWs3BwBlCzeDyZoJCjBdZiLsc3j2JBa1DHLrLs40pNBJRbOI9j3e1Bj3o/lAVw5oKqqQBQgLkF1f8Qdw5PMUQwlTrCZbA75KEPWcmaD1t20Rt1BhOOBDIHjTIkNCEWcMhSMALbBZ4q@M3HyrxKbQCRquFQhXJQfV@PnEVOXpv1LDG872LJjqqX7rShTFkbexYDEHNgEoUi7bdaLxE7hQz5CWnnIGXoqj8LUNACqRCkcfa0FeBNuAABM3JxG7G5JkqJieZPPLaBTkOBozItTL2NWPgzWP3Jbgh0/TPoV6TrcQ60GArCrwVdCNM0COloocxBM0CKiEo2FtbrYbBrkF6DJky3qPYqBHSV1OzQVqm3QrSEoRAXML5VXkS7rBJBiXUoGEOMDjlnBqJGQLekxIUUQaHVEo0nehA@h33I02GO45sGhVgMa58xNlVoJ1DAxAjZCxQN6ym5dWFgvLgga@qrJXLwGygP4HYbMXDer0/fKKCpIbAKukfIhHVc048rBuxOOQXA99wbEBRAk4tV9iV1x1CjSP7jQSBgKySjZzsE1aU8zPrfNSaL2gbHTGQjLUO1CSr6cklCdp9XhvKq6ganaEq6P1RpCoyL8Yn0LeYl1yxQGURbGi6qPCWBSqhEo4hBoJXF5KIRxVuU4bemzR7QiXgJqjsXBo1AP1z0UEPBFFS6AR@pb1VUzkQrA4cDnu@e/ppWdRF7plqWHZxxqHnNI0eOa9jcNmP@@Tw0fHu8TfqC2D0rEZx3iFlZQt5bGpHY6Vjj1JZVS@uh2FMAT@ur4aNEWfDyJLwZoozDqlKkyY0LmOfnEfHn82TBDQhJAelAGb8zak0PAwoXVLDcLtzjTDrJBKQZBDFD8uUQ@bDDAyIOvobPj7PR2/fYuHNIzUQ7ohZb2RwAL5j6tD246noOaeA@V6NNm8RKS4ooJaNw55TUzikj88nqDDPI0NadIhlPjk62D8uE9iu4Z6bvZ5CQVKuB7qUMWypwPO9UcuUFoUB8QemJkuoU8RRlSZcFxK42Zwh8LRs2RL4AAB7N6rDlF7fz5rbBdz35vNGrkoz4ACyE4R5vTKsDzU/FNEQHtjENbGTu6gVJY9pYxU4LWyxAt/ZZquZy5mb2a1ws9WcptkKA@2TUmw5vt44BK9zV0EXdapFCrVaoH/y5BbiLimR0BVQfMzcHlMpLbcnYe9FsVjUTe1B58zpmepLkngyk@OpVNQf71SbLnU3Q@H3x5YXS8f5V4tDWEh9d/dQf@wHFmN0NHZBnQbsfWPLNGzj/ELTBR6xnZ7TcdgGxOHaoZ8gqE1Ls7nbcexbJWSgI2Y1ghMWIH9xqMYYQFtjvaU@I8UK91T5ZIdhu5cgpbV8BolEFCJQKQqvfmlcGECuab5PDr@5D42IlkunA3OaHiBBKA6RC03NkCs5MAUSUgU@CzMYTF7cqu2@hxKaPcBMC0EXRNydei90JImpphaGX4ASn1EKhUGFGtVxy4m6NASHMgvHPtwBNNo0dNTEEnCx2@8B5/NBGj6@4IE@jQUA3aoojooZLh97gEhiHsGPD3pYAIHG2ILxJTuYP4GSoVikekOXHFRvHATpTgcPUKEHjoMECSfsWIB0sGkssAMCFyLzjOzyjPCUyGU2S@fQ5bARWsNkBaVheXzozhkNcXzeaoXzBsEzOg8D0ChzoTKjgXzo4/PBEx6ZcgEKngHqPyj50E0AyUnDUSZlweCTAKjnuTj@BF2XtILjoQBfYQ/3uobdNHlfUOmjgsSUwT6LesPUrvLNlKG8BQZdITcx87vhOSkq9FOfADTKEExKUQ9IjG6Q5HH6FOgl9aXQ85HflEmDideFHCtNJhtlZ2Da8/oc1/Zi8RJNnUSj6peOZceuomtra9FitBJNgmkHTNto2kFTAkw7ZFLIhOFUNFGMJJnQt0ox0K0Wvan6kMfxGvLAGKXCW2sQM6rFYqaWNKqa@Or4jUNRAOUhtIIfgBONl8tojMflyiWOwELbHMr7HvLOSXNoDQQJvgaVndsFDTJEBFDdsaUemiXUO1dTpF8egkJoYvMRG0bPqumz2tnVWStxdhNNYux4ySiD7heD9GJ9tTN0RgMQytVsUdFq8Xg1U6yVGuVoOroRixWUHiRkxOMfF@IJg9M6FoVeZy92dhYFkgrqVJvdIcEbJ/V4PCAU4AE9iha0TbGoelWA9BvxWjwRhbjxaBL6AuVoFOjSRCK4lGnU9jkTHUDn0sXxZeixhocKSZjTUDNW12@ag@5kGA4Q9KihBcXRsen8GlQGmqEMN2xvefywsJ7R4v02jYeDhgs75igLBxMurSWO6VlqZq7XbxUulHbf8YzU5yooREEispuKrkVTipKSGflwSJTtp5aLVdiwTWfkhkcRFg5uYOrgetodgbD0J8KTwFXWQDKbXYdF1x8CdBaM3mKDgAPRCh/O9gG0mir8UIieHh4xHAM1bY9miC2Qizh7zHtcGiHBRY8/7pbLD96oQWolisPSmJDVsZ2hqQBJIIZE87k0@y9VmJgkPqRe7a0xR@G7B0mSUm2ZIBEPeo5BtOXiOjTMO@iH4oPuDVGOzZbUA/nRBvGo8rIYmq3UhkRzLs6wCy0E5AYlsR6UVl94pBx30FK9MUSVYqD0zHhyzQ3UykvW0nU938y1i74fcgUQuwuFhBqnDeqr76Vo4BkXhbzPu3y@/v3s6PE@7xelRu6QelbYR673ndaoBxzMdaJj0@4k2T7wk2U7fQvI4Md/e947dhyPa/BgWdbr4gqx1R/1DOrPzXe5VsZrOg2nR928VVGn4UdD1@gZvIPp@@5@/vTw2fMXpydltRgKlDIu@oIyh@FJAZoH8QdxXc5i8npOxhbIXymCAkN45NFjJNaJALV990109ysHjnQK9wK693GNCOj/Qtcna@AoAm5RQFw3gtPtwvFKS9@g@1JNKQinUbhLXEESwvZK08n9wmu3Z5wz5HyuoJDpTZ2z5MzXj8xocmGUcjwQLiaZCRMGlKcwwZqS@XBCDAVzgF2z54/zH4OKgWPZ0Er3UBGyzUscZ@cLO0y3iZrzyCZZiwPhrNk1hu6tzgXUjoHCQ0uRNeJ4aI1SqINI6ykmBqJKxPOg3PMJBJfLQQcUcOrjbFf4jBIwhjXk0xcpPkS2XgcQ25WSP92/LBimFI0GwQgq4QYxKJs0r3Yrq8EsqUsjXxJFKUluqvrqbKynlbPx5n4t5RIR2kw@Oxt/nNa/kJMMF2SsP0h1zBImt5RaZOejRc0uCACWGM@SDMphZLedXkvhQ9NQ/oAxjT27wVxgsCSERDe4WEN/NYiFs8xi1Q4IvtBCkltw54qucjtAaOlJAAhqwxW7Pk9eXLMqtEUXqjvoWV6N3aieU@9i5r3R0J5fpMKVw@HQmLiSmEous93jTz6vpmscgtQ3cLi5wEtr7K9xAo0WNBhcSgYmnBD3LI@aaJr5szC/mgpIjWlkEtAHGDyBEgsSEjlC1K/N62le2qYHSpSJmLuTfpKZ8Ru13TM8z7Q5b/Ex/@Xk5oOzIpkyJb8jRvqKLE3DoaAyWugHKJbYyenj/eNjFTjUjUX3cdi0CNXOaHZBc1iWaZ@S4cwX2cetKPsY48QZpgJVCroFdREfmLcEzA0dA0gdRUHHHMbAMY4jnk1wpkFmishVJ0EgXNbQ9IhGAbCYGYc8EbDiQvxf2LwPJPAssihLECWB3LEHRaCtFVdHtvVGdaGRIIUSgkR5L5LWr5XXYyS@1rU48c/Q6uOMDXR@SJ@DPFSrbA2kG4WWWfkde1VNK1u1xDqr1Up8Hg4ionZO6@HE2ipD0JMPWpOAFDgfiv5Ve26FnZ8Cja9gLI6fBjwrCb4FZIejxuR2LZXXdTkeIKu8BQfuKc8juWAFGEfRX3tAIoSWKswuOZhd0BDK1gvqLs@t3ITs@AgE@cHJghjPJVsrMy0e9zHjgF4aQ@wEF9lzx3WtRo@WlrV7Fl@qETTWRUEYAcmnTDi5ElYMohvWZ6hnWBjT9YR8lZ6gBPlTQwN9IswZOcTi7AqJSaTUkYrs@hodZLauM2IDGZfzcfre@L1TkI9PHED2iVieGNY5SGiISWQUHWeS7HfDZmdp0Ier@KmLOe1VuZDD8bj2aNnnDo31BqZ6WtVyqDEGsfvnvdsx25bbpddM0AAHHlZfhp3bb7TptSAADXmKyTRyoME0oStDcRqpY/rQuNqClGcnkGeSbZjtkd2hmQc0M@XNHSGVrQIFbjca1rKgQARcDuJ/FwQDWYk1T1ezqubXHhyqgWYR5Cfv3UyzPr/2gM3QHRopD2KJ73/5Vgvof7t0utBe4RhlYKiDpoAlpbSXFpaIihZ6LS5YPoc56lkGEYZMd4FsGkPIktELDItB0wScooC@0cfhRFHiwJv4Al10BZtxzPlsgP9dnMiiAXUb5HZzWdi5tRg8KRr6hY5fi4jAdS7LpEgkZHkhmGM@/BrqgqPAvRspf8EEI2bm5d4deSP@BnX4zkK0BvhbVTdFyHTOaGgmdC2NhmWuKPKhcT5qOcrgvBOoxfkFYae5p/kfBbQSMRVUR@Pi7PMMDq0ONPf@d1mwafuauqTPXVzh2iN3oDSol97iNqoI/RUpDHv8vSyIJbYRBIblVLN69LonJwrowChiJjSFS8yUENGsOTL3jMYEVaHuh3NZMKsIEqfcTCTSmSXTSoPB8vjYP6X4W1uLY4/VJqfHojGEFF/GpvBRNsqwWNh2R6lCc2X1jZ6it0LGpcJ80aTkraDBfAbFMS@g0Oi1ismxQWqOesZwalrB4lM8/GmGZSPWotkQdbnp9CwXK3RvmdT0V8ZM08KFhPQKzX5aiyjZgo4otuNKYFosBZymhyvGlrDVPWQaX6mF6@FCfKI6y4jVdC7xt1SD6EJnmL8XN2pvF2J1D/mk9Jo9A5rypS3CzPghjk/ewauXlmvSazFhzxci6jV7C91na4E/Mhge6buLs12r57jshN6rCNQZAhX4ezFPh2lpGbZC4@Vh8wox5E9xTgvU6HWcXr7QSRnwWlrqo2EbRb/43lfIBUJK0@4QUr4G5Nia@C4V7eep4fldBUQbNIa4vC1kXNHKLpJUYnpmee6gb4Bze4tzdpAuUEw1xccQlySMszKXxsT//gKtxzLS@q3HYEIaNSh4GGGrAAZvyLXsXyS17OrUWvcTSrfAbt6ViVDhnvdMaK/ofatImZ7WPjCGlk7fX0S1eyNzZC7saxw1vjRxj9@Kfsb9kUqLbKyLwXycP8BF6UGot6JzeC@ssalG20phYkCv3bxbm5kVagNQwAfYe34OhudouB2jY48GM6U600Gzj1eTrDvwq7TTmsEOfT5UDhXuUJZmVHTXpN/KThPv5OH6kHI2nU4LHSY0KTNjWdWZygRxv7T4eyZhcpmmPA2LE3HDkHFxGkSW8AqkpSJIX9a3p8BbWynbsk1vgu97StOG4/Q@pKRAqLYs1MZAuaSVdqtK7Ja6I9aQs@nohYtjHo32snEL3tqI7iXQB/vNqwo9PNd0r9JUcF4UqmBnzrp6BCc0c3VXKrjXEoeF@Nq73nJdUgyIaGpB3VxZ67iG6jTMnsE/43x2FbwtNbMS3qzQEPO5OP/LZ32ns/WROaE0mACxrBZ0VLpm3yTrCkXfaH05cv3P0kBjB3/LvMem2UyN983msgADC@SCje@ZaeaQsuQ5NnSxPGPYMbGr0sOFZMJ1mQT2pxMXEvmwb3RMvoF8laScjlngghves5saF49eFPkimyZEm44wL2cJqFTn5sT1vwsBPp00oVxH/btH3OYqfxOHQe9R25etYLvdxNpdp2t3zS5fNhrYllUO4EePb/hfhTpg3ek2GYmm8ArXMD17Tq93H3qiaOSC0nHaC3Hax21vuHHjg@BOjAZ4iM@d43eGx2UHGpbWmq45gnbJdTxnYCpkWxa0h2M9/L1Mhvqz37/oINLKrj5QxP/@ovDv7Ft2DMcbDOhTH/RGLr0oqkK7Fe/Sm9p89QqSnTnDjvrW6TdU4aiKpS006b5YxDQsr9nFXaKcs82O02h2rbuQbpiGZ1vnKX/Uh1vv1XdFylhMeYzOas8C8g4nKvJLOex/gp/DZYUuBpB4sxYYVugriwbpaEOmMjDOmy4fEEUTK@KYcKg28m2bRdrvWnwzsrwp0NByp2CEl89MoGEZ7mJZxlLNipZIT8WwWK6xlEtJSUeFXDHToPBoS8eXZpbChapYJsNfyxAK55IwCi14@RByi@VBNEBohYZuwX2Gv2bWNS1s5OzuqOPeFph8xL4FKhq@ForA3Q6e84Kb8Bzm9pxLWnRGW5ynO/lC49nQmhm2@CwrAL2Xwt1P8K2DNjYyV0645FbOuFA4racYjgWfOnygUEdLR9d61sDlb6a0l87TiYVQ0Eufn0zkVJss7maLImuZbT4/gqa7lMe@QzO4oJ0oTZztx@F1FPNcJeMizXY6IO6VHpsG9sMuU2gWrkxazBhBa6p88czsGLhQ@4nl4UrPBfxCzLxoRdOdsL8@Mlzr6yPI2TI2xF3cfI5yGN7zi7YF8J4aHav56UxBBEgKAotlovwzUzHQ6XZZXHYtF1dXBYYVQ1bIcpyJkevq0KNYEHJ@UD/YwD6t9Xx/1MLQiwbencEEt5FMyLRqzN3yaPxVfJd1KpetO1uJxOWoPxi54rMYB1q/FR6f7p@Tu3tpAXDlDQhd1jV63uIx7NBgLOhnormcGpfp6d@0ek6HfbOQZqDOgXqGavsCxnkEDfdzXDQ0tBdwIqV9zzlRHAJRuOxz30DZmhmmWLblrR7n8TxcQOR/MTO8TcHtDakn@FYffigE5XQxRZ7c3QuY7lm8o@UHzjtxRsOmicbgIIJwh0Gkau75S5dFq2Gbl@H@28p5HWgoHXvkKcORvbJVyK9sFYpsXMiH2IDFvr7/9EU8zA201Psu/dSEbuHI7U2mpqWrCeaYzLJBRVsuR2dD@72Mx/zIlGNaZ3xHnF0816VJ4vqxs6gn9HwyNL17d6VA@I/6j80mzinemfYz56ljO9AaDUBQ9o9Nvhl4ZhXI4ogY7QludwX6tO5M5oTALmmEuLZhDMwGlG9varpPW8QBPzY8Y0lTRKOG1DMMTHfyitVrmMMvaTgwZF7W2Z1F6FNzTL2O5QzD66DiNZtcWcaRupk6MjOX4w4cx@ZvkrZp@GhPV0sVaArodf9ZdBVX8c@MGCzsuc1m9eiCLyExW3y3@rK8Ds2G0@PvFQuWbIsvGDCGlummnuDmZ3LLZ5kC2pe7UoZsrpQh004TaLIXhksz@Is7IVOQ2vgD1gd1jWHTwTkyYVixdCe0Y/kOMR1sDOCrChpA@DFILKM5Esem3YVWr9/o02tpVyJUmsdmA7cUNWibv2eMbxcmHzMSe5xDy72CncG@uMJKnWex59BPid/dbM30sGapag3oRZJ66UQ6reRRbMtsvjVwPM0hek1HrWf8Ic@pZ2RcMoodqkY0vpwyaAvswpo0u64NFJqeqXjdoQnKr7dq4Ns/f2HBTMmob@L08@z8zFLV1XG7lFln8Ux7IFyHpiKO/QJZEhwBxvVDZXep5ong4f/o0ddS0AjX81n/TAIQXXfP7QPyo6EtPvfhwOeO67Wt8RHgjTsSlokTzFYOosCH1ww0bSzLBJSePerxcYlOaFFWv0XdMYWOnVSUHolrz1RM@0KhE6LGt3Pk8B1jqV08x9AzW4rYII1zEMoTf/NYEEx8F0ythmUjrgTVUpyw43xWrA1dRNxLXzKAvuV4ysClb2rgPj98cnSqDlxtca@/izs1bulxMzuu9UI6NFj1pTEMzYTytWoty/VSj040Ze/JoYoBltCbz3Uo8ME5u5nP0hFRcWqgkTKW9oLQ1/QWK4ifnj59kpju72Sxve7Q6ZvxsPfeyUkSd7187WShdzj2AdSOtjNeGv1wX9PiC9j3hU3zhsuk54KUlkE6NaE3Csz4KT@w4U7lqukMzNbpZGB@Do0nSnD3nsnnl2bymXFhdbAWsq2lhKKKyrbUfDYeWrYNnW1zGHyXlee5NUBp2aRPin@WLlRBzSGTGmYWaw@r1gLMazEsLdYofFgkLX2bWz1LgZrR6aIpZbh/X8Q0TVtG5xOjDeXKcksLazbAopnjnnNxj0lmU3RelMBJ8YCrFOvOReabSh9EdwpfOHAvHMHYWLpAZhWAwDm/sMJfmvbEsBWa5VqlXhQhNi53Wxnkm@Y9pqqCtT8XeJbrwtm/YL09izXJGL8j4dNhKMre3qPDuyIcC1quDvXJsxfsueE2jd4dAcMYm/fAeKoZfanguBUejbV0orU1BFD6Knh808jxyA4fNugmxZZyvteL775xVf9EyFjMSCTi8dnzhsN7jfguGwNPm6YNMhD2@pqtiX0w4BFsDRK7b/D8Zmh6TdyzJvkgqmz9SuxVKRa1G9yvIxdlJvYSBad48ZOoyusxPEMHUMWT1tm6v8mF0Qmq7JpR8wv1XculwaamwrsOS2L3DytCks8Pn@@fnO6evjippms3clzsceNoGQYk5O9@/DjTkiE3ghDQKvIj6WiXXA@So9Ndsdl2/SwxyNRcrsozuZrmR97BOOtXhpFK0WavlHID@CkyT418oY6iE4ft55goLvbqFfkeqR5RU17noGVKE0qhyNKLEh4YrgvZEv7z50uTL8tk0JcnLE4RAybrOE5LpOia7O7HT/Fg9/DJi@N95iM4ZYNLq@V1y1s5fsgcsr5iQjm1LZo3LrOoiBKFsiqXowdRIExUjbIibbGjA96AcyGYTx3cnCdib7DYOsEHCkaDQkn9l2@lbqIqLoGKQ9ioj1SUCcpjAHaK22b@7Hdb/ABUf9u7f4D6sE8qJ21KlsSWuCUb4pCiVNUGy49RpwNHae9bcNLp9Gh6iY6@Ba68RE1k/jSTOB0wwM/EF4fN@AkRg/iHJmKPGQ@OAXX/wsKNbxyHNp7jMsvKOP3GcLOwynbxjHjgeWB9RAJQH9kePytB7MeOAB@pgYhIsnVClp/WK4cCRrfXgJUbZseymWuDGmJ6RfYl8Bn2Sot896WiVKK3ovig@eUAStfr90IBbx384qbOvNT7X/teqlNiYB6nH4HtV4StDeZf5eZXKSzr24fDTNMPI2FireNY88QDmiO9Q8fh23yX65RYeIaNL/uY1YeiuSBKY3CeAn8rNpOncGLVz6GggMWglMTuVp6eOazFup43KKZSyEY4wq/Sij5zzKfXVWDy1JsRnvrt2G4qn8tntRQgqVz4AOmYxw5uHeIA4/EiML50YQ3KrxvAXtvbTMZWzSznS7w0U@vGq4z8OkB0HcJKl11ErsogDkSZxgC/iogGDURCi2NUlEdRLYqiqOVAy0H@2MKg3RaEkFkMiMVpZOK5gWO8F8EbTnDkY9Rr4QFEthM6AnhdAFI0aH7IFJclsSHzmeMBy8xsReUbMnF5CW@lcDLW5fd@0EHlyIPq7do03UfknzUs6peK9Z6DyqTnG7xw2covEcQJgijKi1i2@oqdeWd2LcV5kwGb/liwbJiZbTD/cqqzhGd5vndvH0sVmz9UConFHp7YDg4mHkBmWExP6ZmUlo9Ps5TNLsySyJFIBrKDW@yvITkQTSAmmqb1pTNwd/f2D7929Pzk1tFLFDI6HwwkeWU7caaoyWotMETD2ZotkkcHqZOnjw78gpginQ9JYNBHRE60VTmZauUIcrr@cz5rizCcz91yjF/yTWLz@Gb0VahRpFt4aOkPSJfWYCkHtJJ6PnG9sIhaudwqlKbwUiHQe3wbzC1UY/Grm2ptu3JmR6K3OWFBRXgVUTewEoDpzN1YTyGz384cZiy4n@cUbxdww3Uxs7guyusZPDcEN@J5zvn0xBThEPII5ddPBkSkpKb8oEtr3xHXo6cn9Oj8/iB@wkj4XIUQwvn0KoqHQJ36VxGhFJmeLyaO1uoabrdnNST/PAt@xJZ/ElBwuhY/iyIWl8QJtDzhmLicaFwcqzStGoujtCNYSbbqtC4fXlyCCo362vMRdAWfOwN@IiENnz82fdOxA@L38YjPw5nsa6M@hGvT59ikoQyQ3ApEBkpGA1S5/gRSQhzWNU7gcWiQXhWP7BIZV/utXGwcV7vmuGV1QLbH4kmQaB9rWo0FB3phpukALzsqU5lNS2FlVfwENzeFyf5Bp7qNpwgYVUO1oO8/jkUvo/FiDdJH9@jly4toXF7ES3S6nDhurTV/zFyA/qa2WpIYnqid/hlui6TF1tZtKQFu84D5qSr@cehbW2rXlehCizLq4ife8AkYQY2ItfvGgMVGNj95RmVkjZ3F7CQd1aFU@DFUNkskqIsEH/JQGcVsk4m33zHDnrBYqgxMgK6u3cLPW2vAqpqq1sBMicTZOl5TsAcaF57iEJegnwpRigS2jCwEHQfAiFcSlTM4xEF/CQ/XGNL5PQu86dR2Ggx0kCaUa1Z5wEIXTcxqjvLWVlEU6KxU3GLAfbfFoZoCsLfknK/LA3XFLnGgGXRoVSkyFeS3JV6E0o1wRD4V28sBnUjo6Dh/1zkDWNOD3ZrdIf5i@zbUFTwoo/ji9KBeiKdkFmxT7wytFo5I0LFvkaDTJs6ihmqamgkaLfE@2icYDc8fqvN98Hg8zgFVGHlOpEbCZJi/cm3Km5q2kutFRFEKEDKLDYBYy1/3weFBW/7c0AK/xcL@5z/HS93k2PpOPlPvXSSiuXQJXlopx3Ls4/UzRVmv6rl0@eF6zTC8M5kZqezG4wuz224cdlJnsswyLJtKbej5N@cDLb/xqqq@GdfkaqGcPK89P2fPn3/xrv4uLo8vJvJZjG1G2N7RtaxBBiLFTbbF8LfwoRuXFj7LuuhyFICySOTsDC9rkzflVKoarcE/@b6Gh4erVtSKulN79y5e3YQ8jSdnEbwHiR09nIUX0/X4iWVZKXY2cFst@DldVuO3@EX4k0jEFCYclCp3Y/1xm9zGu2anM9o3Jtzdiozwc@CJuE@/@fLlSzS8pIe9PRbxOXTmp1GsG7kI09P6n/107SZ59by@/Wff7qfMNfwc4ed7N0/RfKLlPl5b@/jRo2w2CVTi5ufffP6N3d3d7ONk7nk1t5NV0mvbf/ona2u6vq2n1mquq9Wi1fPzL2Q9nZXVP/tJtP78@dddF4sFnwzTwIjvAvw01KnO2Vt4ztsM/8n8thUyG2hutN8yPfI2AmwdmdBfPcJ4LSyTlhR@1phW2dn8rz84ehPxIhU99XIIXy/yJpIvRLgRDGDL@LaLSCWyjcHyN5FJqlwug3Hzv/47iF/5GsBBn8k2vCo5H1Z@EqkoZYpyHankwaDpOqT7f3/rW0sHfB5W4ZGzm7q8U4Nng55tCU8FUtKp1FxorfBAe8CY7XU908GPxT82fJhRsqG7fVxNJBI1VYFHrVOklKbpZzRSE@YpGmiJBM4lxl1YyG3KIMIF/F5GiJmAm4ihuFk4EI9xh5fz4V4ueEov/3GeYymSX3toPq5UQPLpFX2jkqBn7axYJJrXU2yzIDvOQxzAip7JUfaaPREkrsjpgi4nk8mHdbwRk42Rkso4MiUb45RhkRl6RtjUxsJOEeZHY9MwHxpuH58//9///Id//gP6@yH9/iMem2S3rHZqoxrbiNcu6hX@sEpFrgzlqzOyPGTpYqFYSJEvyKXaMdPSn1xHc5noCbYJ/uMPaEaCp1LBl48G2ioR7lLhpqmb8KkEFgoxjbI4HBOCyCdqBFpcsYZEqV7UWMXP0KKn@hCKSdY3t@RaRc/pR1B0mkwFt8W66y5zIn6O2A48a/BH/2trKA8CF3yv4UPvHR50wbMWYHP3M4@qFKlGqimzho1EEOjhWnGtUMwX9VSdLQdUWgY9chGWI@qmWlB1kBwKq64dc4avsYT/nCXufF6oal0YyeDgT1GccUSK/CM8FYlFruCpvduovtuo@0lXRWVNbCu1SkJgBB@1/rCWUG5uquqrRKkk/rcrgbFET6LE0Ag5qd0oyvYrAFadBRvNOtG88xChc@D0VuuvtgF8Yru6XXb26KdSdVFqryrV7VkQArmHDxMoZh8CgMp6jcUTiXVFWasuzQMArMUY9ASgAG@2byo31e2bm@1t@N@m9434guvN9q1/@kyfJWGm/jVktLNqqnKWOhNsUwO7mqqgi5o6A0MFvhAOWiAp8g6aFfaUP@ypbcM//IQDfG180GSTJ7eT4akfSDhzFymywZhZ1Db0TCo3/ji/DwpVtaZgv6esVLV8rkYqjRS5Rg0AauyWFElhP2GLdxe2yGULNL/UBtuIDJi2mYlsgHhw2Rr3lyKQTwBwRfXr9fuv/lf8nb3/6vdZ4w3@PXmLf288/Dtt4t/xG/xjp2/x79jDv6cN/Hvu4t/pG/zbbeDfaR//Hr3Bv6ce/r3o4J8UKYMWu76T7qUv0tq5dg4Gi6WHLN1Nd7UWitG0ydKT9ISl@47WApMJf2kwWek2S3dY2k7bmgaeYPBY2kNTGz4d@GsDlCH8Wek0Ak9fMEilh8KZbg@g7zU06/Ezqcqir03QNlVNTat5q17Dc5lBDS1FUmdnKd6hZnq2hMcz39zU6/vPHtfrKZqXOXvqHE3/j476YevK//6R8/TI6Tvwf3R09PQMNJRK4mFCeQhPuZLYFp@dSKW0c1ZUkPX9WhZJbe@cVTIKmvMJqDg6uiU@8JlChG9l7UyKskto8i9LpE6ULi9KlyUyBNaXpTqY/QAiGDeAY0moIeAC8c5epkiDuITnguCSDY2X4OmbuCH18vIMNWroKgX/QI@w9R/g3/r/1v/TFyxWrcWh23J1sx2jJ45/8fjVzdWNeFfisZiwxLbhDx3AjlGubipopEBXYKrG4rX4zQ13g3csvs0BVjCN7QpFngaEuh4J0qR0@Sv2D/vFtMVzhkcGh@a4z87G6XS81PCPKMX5HeOaphrjJbo6Yr1R1Wp/@hM6iHYnToFy2VJJ22Dcomf1Uinr2zYLpVLBt6zHYlu3n0p6R8uDmpDNxuOlElh2fLBpsAZgCwDWt@QAqukaTar9pUgcM8ElQixNhzfjif5RuSg/eBATt4Dt7MYfPNC30tfXgctgAE7ajFO93rKG9Tq6Z66v5bpM08xbObCnC9fXIJ@icWcYe4YXQUBCMUVjH@sVSnPLGULeN8GbaSl9ikXXcA3PG8beWoOkjMsdXTlO57Sn087wLPqz73/722fRcllWZHLNaggAU2G57e18tlLJZ8GcLwBx5PUrfmVBJ7GlxW/WUzInAJPXoxHhpRU241woRtGfRbbZTgXqtIsPu7qJUEmzbC4ea0zM@BW4@G7a1hZ3ZNl8rJDYEn/ltTirQCPF/7BDl0lkNzY3HmKPbrzkQUFcujLL2k35yizigNhNqSmu18FNRuaDB5ktIGghXTqT6vXHu6e79XpZhvZQxrs8GDqSSJfw5o/BMFqlMaPcVq2KmaudRaPF0kNiBq2QY5FoSYRTotA2sMIW0UCy2riDEDKOMJf/nj/Z3ds/Terb0GjrB7t7Sf3kxaOIhtbc1E7eGbQf7@8@PnoBEZ4/2d892f/k8PP9F8/B3WWX08eXr@I9/YZNC@yX7KX05fCtYZqGOTLN@uVodPmGfWlZdQvI2BtZluV0hsw166ZpDiCY/5Tg17Rc48svjeGAHvb@x999/@P/9v1vf//9b3/3/W//8Gdf/fC78Ptd@H2ff7//b7dy@P7ZV//T77z/rd8Gx/8Ivz@C309/9tVvfIv/yP7H8PvPIbc/Fr9QOP6TANav/OyrH/zkZ1/96o/g96/E70e3f7/208W/H35n@Q/j/eB3Vof5/r@D3@9xWH7Y7/8Wd8PvrfC/xcP96o/e//q/5/9/Kv7Q@Nvvf/2P8SUs/@xHf/qf33/7P@h64U//zfvvfv/9d37w/jvffv@d773/zj/V3//Gv9HS4dfvvP/hH/zVH/7eX/3h/0j/v0vv37vP//sf/bO/@N/@4v/4iz8Uv5/C79@D6ad/8R@AZ//2D36M/z/4g7/9ox/j///yr//2D/7F3/7K/0yG3@SG/@df/Vv@/utf@09/8y@/91c//dbf/Iuf/s1v/sFf/Z@/@n/9xn/66//u9//6f/g2Ov7mT//qj37lL7/93b/8zj//y29/teT93ZXvr@7h/tU/gsv98bwPnPvk60NdvvqF8Pn7UGOaCvAJMPgvv/@NXwIe/3Vu@@/BBv@B1/cCy4wPt3xvagEI/3JBpF/@2Vf//CeB7ZeCgBGzONtoFPRCYgOU6Y2tLRoK9P22b0OB5L6HlXImhe9hdX7/42@9/8k/ff/j33z/419Bwa1kt5K7SUVbvewMelFK7h7hMGD@PuEwICT/xRfwGidoCE1JoI19IQJ88cUX0vg6BV2a9MNrcP2CnPjDuBf4MeHl@wl3XLAYDsONad@4js7X4aTBrIlh4DVJpy@@JC2B38QamADfDSmXARuhjj4bfm4SUk7zPSICFvcc03D/GP6l7BaLQKTxODGGPhAYEmOWAK9HCVYulylyeUxBwYpxxqxSgOBjHKUpI3SIxOMk6wUEMX5EUCBmOXHM6hvlMY@YQHgVgkDIodOxrOlyolB@DAmWx48ZwkLgBPb163KlUB5XENw7QgESSjwinBBYOTGuvAN7mWBCPCny@B2gUignEpUCJoiZ5LRK1ilNLUeZo7wnGOUb3Rmtw9x5yNjHslYQiyXXkGA8NL4T09A7NBmyA/5niQ2RHfr3jfTbIIKvUVIiFV4smNgajy8CAFxFUVWVwU9REJuH4D3moBKULHwSCVGsAA8fHyQ4QAFjWSSofBNkgfQj5Y0PfhIV9gEPH8ss5OV6QpvooJXK@U0czPwnt57/5p8seha74iNxmq6vr0uRipyRj2heIAFd1eF5kR/Xf807B0Um57dkdDZpoTCnsbn@nLrbG4834K3B//4ard9NsBIRZz2KozpRxnPNPk7w38OHG@xjKAP6Tt0kpiQyThYHZ5Hc24mErEOqFSchvQJpJ0ElIkDXkjou02xEQkomGVPLEfRjR0dHAjVyeFWWElAH9YyGdhxIHo1GEYihqkkVaMq/Kn3JQRUGlXzFV13HkqcrwJiuZ0ug5JcYOrGwTq5BZw0d3717ByxDc/jFQ@hTMTGdr2cL5AkOfN9WrzfxF47r2S2J9yGZlufXXsbo5qw4i0ssxjbiEl/tyZEIZgejeqEQRVMcykSNbfirO/KadFrUUSxJ@8U0sm3i8PHx4UmRcbQEkWIBpHiJxt4ENlsasXrTRCXYf0rSU7fzyBlDJzEpy0ktj5OmcRpzY9I3nGKx/E7LbkrwJfuI4QEsfLcWVD1ciatubzOiW@VKoXFINALd8lKlIlZoME2qnOyfQoTTI6bpaZVBF/Iqu6lnc9mcnsnnc5u6ls1vZfO5QgZEfT6d03VtK5vdKmxt3jD2WmVFhV/WphXycRVnQOpOu46nMqnstVT5go1VzIxyI1V65Z5pd7zuOi6ckM/ScogI69V0Ev/0TAbekGRSy23W1tZ6Vwrm4IyK4wpXwECq0pUC3M4@godJH0nsI3CCB9LAZS1MrCk6PCqJhR24cTrGV3fIWg4qVVw6A0Q5OGkQfkoztgHw8NXVVegnRda@@U2PVSrQ3VMOD6QICKwu81c6KFZL7ap0I3VrhDfRg2@HsZb1uYWXJqj@9fF6Jq1KkZubmzZAOjzAeTGy8hgtfN80yaUB5puxIf3/zz/4s82PF6ngAnbHaJWDW9yhosavWuWW06TrVErtcrVGt@OUWmrDaU1U15sAe4vCLEcbPad5HvU9Lbx5DndflVNGSq3XgRs8p14vl6OpVHRH38wV11LDlEqnKbFYG@r0jp7fBMczm7vG2uCSQ5dXs05bxZbqI/UUWBfi6UU9n7vZFmeMVSBPiFoFEbkS@BVtxzZvcOl50WiDHLxq8vVFRVnPFeRStTS1b@blUu3mYd9sWQY7S@Ny46uFEfN5@cYPB0mbUOloN0usj3d64KaFYvosHV8SOQ2RAWXCVNoWx5pUaL1MFWRLDS8orta2/QNPKhKTdF3RM0pGU7QM/t9h0PH//uF1@NfxDbEyunSKh9k8g@IGGWqzJ3jyquewU8ehS3Yemc0lIfa6Bi0M2hs6rvv3CPPIsM@512OLn7QReH1q4Onabt/yuktCvBj0cR@VOfxHg7DfbwCCyIM8wCN4DXuOsyjAJnvxfEkunwZnWwEx@OFWEPz48JNPT0Pf0/3dvU@lPHt09Ozx3CcnAuXYk/2D08C6yX39qLkAxDf2nzyZt4pPBFtbHJFbY7lN36BJuLLwAXQkHghjLj81ptH4km96sdxgpRvf3VSUTv2dMFQ/rIbJmnxr21ga8@3VQrXQNrckacBs55JtplnL6fUMvGCsvQaOXQNX@JvYqvfoHjxM@tIZ9lpQxcw16SluJtjS8BYlREL6FID0R03ay2h5Eh7W0cKrv3D4t4H3EI/wer0ljvBBJzQOrU7XY96l4weQGobB4PehD8Q3w4@32sHjaZDbLZ/e7eBSRDI8I1IoAcN6N6WWPdIePNAePB8Cg1cK6WLxLH0DHFZ@dF4cmGPPNQfu/ngrC/zGRuwF1ABj2JRlvYjSMpHC3ilb/@t/@bs5WQatkMlyXts4YNkkq6v1iLGBBdGxKiloDHBw95gVoMjpFJcs9E4k5N@NFIiqiCbLtL4xLamk3elbhVxhK6MXkoWtQjan5XO5pKYnQX/d3AJVJ60VtHwht6UlC9mtTBZUK/DNbW1KEb6aJLVBIOFbBLB2Ey/92cbbkxy1W5EifC6AvY0ZcRYxAvuIySbEkfHCVmhocAPVhlWW9SyD/jqo5wDRYE0WOTjYSx8cyPIjtOCs5l5alltoyRXS6c1HsmySzx6of7osOzxOAXdIyx63pNOP9mR5xAHg4WKy3EXLfh5HAWTZQsve7sEBptNGi47xIdg59@GWnm/ZhGA2WjIZGkaQ5TcBOAi3yxPKEqb7aME00eeA@@yBnyx/4uOTTgOEYx6OQ/jUz@vuriwfcsvuLvrsUcZzHNXP0LJLjywPwQJ1Q5Y7YOhgiyfLDTBiDZHlJpiaEwPc8IolPIHK9gxZnnACIYlkeUyhjea5LNd9d0zm008/Nbpey@zwZzLkX@DMQ/CxxqP9g8YnnzQ6ncZwsrv/yTH67O19arQno2Gj0xDRGnV4HIgDPuf9yfwDOB7W60Zvoc9n4GPP@dQndRNxqxtvACfxdDCRfn0PfPbAZ9FMCocGTx@CNvB51IfvI6NBPv5DPvQdNxpyCRkVN5HTPYlQZ@jKwmTfaA6dEtrH5TXGorFoclLNp2sl8mB90NLSpRu6IDFGN0xjdxL0qatJdVxO18rj8qbOp97bMflsrOcsObnW39G2QAUzdjQ9mxgXcSOl046yqKLtxLQHG29jz0DVymSL8tnOjiJXtdqOrhWK@c1XGyNZjhfxvZPZLL6FblkUenr4ilc3azug102jbG4mjJRe3NyMl26AHB60oI2RZ9brsdilaZzH44gudk4gC/x6xgnl0yq1Y@PkuMyxYpN4aVzWSvxwFJa@BauFJ3GNmp4z5BA7AG68ky7SBZCytlWQIf1UKhaPg2QiIQLf6bKUl18/PT89/QJkFvQLRafpOb9VrCSsn3y6p0I/StjwBC31ANVkZ6juoWCZ8eEHPPlOpyBy1U@hGQSV1XfDpe1Dp6fuj6Gvi7q27@Gfi6KK0yzU009n4JxAj5GnjDsDS7RV3G6aDA8Ys1rMKFfAZLRYjLBiRvySGuB6pVKul/v8DsdKEOszfp31FMyhy3EP9itS9Ctc7i086uX0zTT8s1GfPeKB6E5aP1q9/Aha9HTJxoM1TbSus3FkLFVaePbYo/Kjq1ERByluSmbZxLsu5QjuJt6xyyPbNdrmc3OI23MPj9ZZm5mvm7hQ/PUZ3Yq5h8r4jVIZMnsGj5ihVBrxWaeQFQkX@zqoIZwiV7RnAacub6BbE3sVL70B23CdxVrqo/hOtgQkfMTqLA5u6dft122ms3y2RFcFsRgCg1pGxKMLJ@PlymcAm4M@LxYBF8EE5wAW01qHToHVIh8jPrBuSp1yFUNf42tbkeWaolSva1KlJFWg0pYmEaPsjhp0NiVLNzQ9nS@NwU3bzJa6rFFuvBqXhuUBdK5ZqQflLkYU@F4MowTUAzoBnLfXLPb@l74V31ZyZe5YImDXPdAioEEvj6eFlClX9Ww@qeezOACRz8BPS@oZHZdUJ/X0VlLXoJ2G9hviw28T7Fn4QRhoxnUNhylivZjMmJxMj9OqltRMLQn5Tr@2Wq/jyfMYqCJEs3jSc/bxnk1wQBYCtiUrfI14Qt/oxVoOM7YVYmKQIyXKp5HssoEFL4RzbBo9Hj6usMxGrLcew0Drp6PBfrVWLO6PB18Hr5jyZief2Ewn3sbjpRgIz3jZNd8QlVHsEBUGa8DUYvSFuaN@Nb0G@b5S6soNFLe3rm3qxepovapokMH0dWdbrsg1KK4bJrQclCZc0ZmqKlM3vJeZLqxl2pZeklSa4eYBpYGQcEg0FjuT/S1HsWh0U49G49ESjnmuyWKcDMQav9MW5Gv0gbYjg9IkF@UtHQNMpeMtZCI3EnaCWXZLilxJN1c32@FR4M/YZGIkFN/6gLFOYl1iKVrVBCofWyOTolZoXHy3vNs53hVXVrPdPSlSZCy0JlxiZ@LUg9QaYx@6lCqxXXnFv2e4XhFSlehEmyqr0WoH08LuE/sc99/tsChkyxj2q7qeqVX1TWgSQcz6QXVdK60nUiyCCyLVCpSHeyURTViEr3DXgxXuLDSxRSv4UtuJSupMkmWSTGKdSqyQw4FHEzL8LsJlwd6VP1xSxIPTY0aRV/xqLf7umdW7KmQU3qMHYXRzQ2XiryX@7LWeg1KyHd8BujUeCHlosXI5HJuLpF4P3G/qhczTwyP78fDA9Mfjs3W5EmFpTcFVuqWicM3xUXp5q6DL@nkywh5GShF2rkS1Iq0/ZoOTrVebrwqvnr44enF0IEXO1q7XHBysZX5psnf2174OAaOZbJSxs3JkXM6WxAqVSkXRtnW2A4Kd4dXEbS2vpK8rnIEr5JHXwef9L/0oO94ugF0HpbUIxZBL6JWKtqGzeGTw/qvfx83gV/uf7z5hUdeYsL/7k5/om3/3J/@aln5Eb0oujQtuRiAkGrX8ZuTqanB1dQMP98tFahGOVHYzDma@0kiLTJm6mDKMjc1EVn9ol1IirLapxSOuEhHD3Zu5iHstvPR0Abz2jrhNzufkeGT/2Mrp2sNt5BNtEZ@Y7lZEihSevr5mDCzNSqvTsXQypVKs@E5h2@@UbfYOh5zfKWvsdbmCE5Aa7p/wh003KpUKQmHRSiK1EWV6DvyqN6VagtGwK/TuXpkb9sbZ7LTM2Rrb2rLB3XQ3XOG04ULPbMOmP3PDdcHq28yNL10m42h@KtVq0fTXtslyFSj5jRSgcxZ//0u/oev5v/uTX7uuX9e/AHG/tbWV1/TIz7Wf/xwCrNix6/ezaIQZt9aiIeifsSUXaKpN6BriraptxsP7vTXsnzHQAayODR1wtEkXqNhQydT5MTCtGAXbwA19SVKT6ZCGeEmSAnWS1OBhp5kkGGwDjzCGKildSR@hF7SWrAyiUvpoCorh5ee9ntOsu73RcEBD9zGKp9WS7AFEgRQ@wjNz1sQd5SRvFa2Ei4FvReUou0Q1UnFY33RdPIEHWgbpI4jyBBie7kViAwP3zGJIywYBr2IQwpM8WlVIuwZp93iEOrnGKPc8QJJx7HgkG1Rl6SNo7IkKFigBzNqGACUQKR8BASAPMQHYqrFtlomzKyuRKE2P97nBJaP8anKxiU7CaAgNL64PIpcwHDiBio5XHyBfiBIGjSvk6APhMPjsXhmUfIxONlSiaEPtvUEBLDq8IkZZYw8eTLEql61WnFGOEP65NcBhJioHezGuAMzvHn3cKspJZicSWNgfzbIdUDxB6ALXKfzEpFIoKpPReiNJ8H9vpkWOnCsq8ihhBkR58VrRBJJBZCQ7L8Mm2y4zTd@MswD5JuDeJKToaJ@gz3c2/ljVv/A9bwDDn0f840MlvIw8NHQn@HZ@wyaD1m6EZzfisR1cGIiNlvxgDpRih54fO4gFWbF6FJpfYk@zi/4pP7GMFsdo01ORCA9aEapnGS7NzMXxQ7EwNIOvgefZiHTWaLy96UCBugPHpgNwaLM@LnQFjgAZJc4R4WiP7Es861eUDUUOY@TSGSLI@YgxHehD1ydRXJxXbAyh2@rTJsnMjsqa/RbTt1iMGI3OO7EDcHGKRAg3TDx6aug0emYfUDoxTYZnwLjFVKoDOs2oQYe@PLWAr7oHFjQltpsSN1WlLq1zK3WKZxUqThu0YrGFNoJqEFY/PoUpDljpOc4561nnJh@Rjc1sQHaZnk@CIpoEyk5/QNgiDv7qmSRLg3eSh4LfJnw2ubGQDMVdi03it78ZbS1WxxK9pjbJGuItVBeGHaIvPdeS6NO6E9c/woA24oNdDUSuKTYvl6O4bzLYlS@JwxjKdA6AiqPygxhoaf4hBmiUBkPzAkIomoRtDAjNpr8dGGsx5PYjagCo7kHNwvOMvGERN7EDJsNWrAlVTwh4m33MMrpEt3/QCRPiNAiAgUVfnoUOfhAV8@F6LSgYlU8Kg1yB2tlvgR/uohTsh/F97kYznTU1ZW@2JsBho0NplRmvFr4lF7Jg7UB@pqyvgWceMFyAyVpMTgDYhByXOegg/nx0zu0SyZIiuw0pyRCCIDVAIVXBv6aOhQ7llcDjkeHyE@3EyUeXl5cqHcE1Glqq6eJBtS7evZcadCzQhp2UZ/YH4koQCy@JEnCnJoWfT403Mu6M6S7ErQcT/pWktlsWO9lj0bYbxcbxAs9h7fTp6A48M8Mlhjqw6AznZoxmq13Bf3oteeXzXxH5TylEbxAIYwhmnJwkm0kAlmw0z5Pty1ZJeFxQhQTgUIqm74gn3g19S9/1TdagHYRwPFpj7tsbvfOm03NQJ5H5WOk0aZ5DP@TEtwr7wBpDJNu8ZLvDoTGJkX8cQyMDxyak9rAJNPvkA0ZoZtgVP4PNGlcntZno4yA6NGrBxPAQz@WQrlYD5Qfyof@Y@4/Bf8z9x9NE/WSr4xpXydDpBrODXI/HOfkhEczED3PDD6@b@hBkUKyZxkFgyMmM2w38mmWK7dOb26Acyz5jAE8MgOBmLFV9dVY9q9mueblRS6Q6wOwyEQJKHEBXa0TTy1ZgRur3LnoDx51xsvEUL2iVBN7o1OwKbuC8gnkMCogYg9PLwoOXOn2VD@1whUBkGCCgHgaeqBrsejErXgqOdCRPYJyqPKUxR6wqkKmR9iW8hBuoS5z0nLBhQLUQIHQPsgRogg/zaw4/ltyXDi@HeC@rH1ahk5T7eABItBYFSs5VFS5rSlRIIawUxUcTyI7qank@K74/FEV1ziuUzRtR/mH01z4Y/TbUi8XYE8PyBqMkhauKOTZBrTZFdSGqsko5VK6AQWrD6JlDaLn2uX4qWmtIZiPldzN4OpgF9xJvYYuFCr8Z5@VDG31kWy4GrDAplyGLkzKvlrxe@CTlBA@iuSLaxGcEEZ8LEICRXhjNFNHG4WjjcpkLDjZeEu0yhOSYkBzzKDz0eAmSNRENek/B9Z1YPDW8Zx40LRngabwZBTVoIDO8ig0nn7/Ew4lwWlKkOZU5xAWCh1DFRj5r1hamXg0hHRJacwCQEW8BaPEbTorSvMDTlMAWyChOSl9GcZtgAy4rgMFIBJf4AX6xgMmoDwwKv5ygdgDqrpyoSrKGS8noL81/ctJ39H/abcf0bEht1jGdnPv7R3GsIWVDFTSkfWjpLApk7Mm8EJfWzugcEbwMrOuAVte4dFhsgbIN7in/vttUo@c0Un0DF3zgvQfBLbhxv/@A8xvs4cDxDM/JZou802QR2y1Kn/cZrI7tQNckfHAn6Hotx3TtqAeF2nQ6tuWaSbx3l6vsJi0/4Cf/SmE9WRgdV5LE0CPvxiJozleo6tbreBNTvR5zzV47XgyO30WriuwZjUrY/wVTKD6IJwH0aBBz8EZxL343TDxjVkQ7tZrnsaOB8IxCIrsMZFgT9H/w7YIGw1xn2nOk0y5RlW54MTpHuev0nQ5ofSNXlTD2HPjDKWxEyBgMCJckM7BLWwwdMky1JNZMGnER9bMPjso@02NGPIivzwKYIUaSDedpjJQdLkiuvjQ5Hs1P7@TD8T0J43uyGl/qhc/jzLvmZe75YUlnYlMIEHCKRuZuNDDrILdat9CZQSVwRr2KR7g3ii1aUNVCTHch6K4IrraBP5KBzQVbgPjny@i/ugD96Pv3LT4Dr6c7mYC86eM6vxid/O3685UxCH4YR9lzO7mAtR/fMy0Ii5cLHKAKAWosCS4bD@qDijmAbrcbHB/tA76D53Fd1C2@p8VSZe65AKfhRZKd68uL6HG9ZfaMidmKiZDJEFw/x8fQYSN5db@Mo6Ajoefwvl4M2q544AvNOBKdByouYRkjeRGPL2crHsQKuIdGygnDw@X0Q/9bohmH@Mp8tBr6AdEoHhplX1g4/DmYDCb8LNgeHVjty1He/vCSxL3NdxME6CAWqSenycZXic/jWJCle7QIQVh1Nst4VKMPEU9BvF2GH0aiu3MKhRuKVPZLWZo913xxiVurSjzEFT5P8mmj@7HkXUx3b54LsRoHNhVhex/WhNyCjEssms1YGCJ3WVlijn1LJqAbjdPZS1qV@gKBGsQkSedZ1N0m/SIuYc/4EL444PQ5fBFgx/TqnKH8vOGYlrhJgZFP3xiEtBbhAko6QAlRkZNcoBEKJflmCH51E6TZXJpm81aazZk0gxowm2QokNScSVKUAhbPqiLomW1viXRGL@w7w2eV2IbHdowhjlZcRa1o0Uqy6EW0CAI5akaL@zEQytFWtPiYDG60eEKG82jxMzBM61b0Olr0qwUGGIKVDA/RXYhwtDejxb1Y/EbyjHPT9dNVo8WgTCHMDrcSRYAUmG/QGnGKzXZENr2hCQ0bKZVJhhzjJrH7ROMwSfql4Z/fVEAnnqMnjnFuUGCWYNpMoxFqMXg60Gz4J@ouqMlF0ZrvHx3QEqUgCCaTgD5eOA6BBzU8Ep0VRhwx9KUZDfgCgig3i4sxYqGW7J7oiNSBQ6mQZ9Mn6qmkD7Ri5F@FwLVpInQ9hYjvl9csCF6A98MTIy/D8xY6fnKEEc7JxheghUR9HV2RKSzrWVxE6YdLiMa6ZwPh/Y5@EF5KBDYk00GHo8k5TGzgDGaZhHxxqbsVjkODcrxSIvfORSOpIGrmEm9yFjlDwRCu/PFV2QnFQ9RmRBB6VtM1XsuCdoFkMXpNZV1IU@WVD1AIyRyo4WbznK7@eCyMFI6LmyS1FcuaIT8uT5Ik16yYhMgqHtIyMjyeetB53cejWz6s@@rHHONYSwwBhGIGqXD56nyA/u5w/d1XqH0izCWwSLFe3JTeVq9XtrJzmPemyd4uQPRMssfxhcpRkMKU5NA7CGnmq3jtloqPSz64ks8TDaDPafs@2YI@wR10m@9bcFioJQwvZh3PdXA815cT6rZG0rtQfaVFxZQEHJ7xANNp1lbjyjO@qIjRh8a3jd4HF/BwtoDDhYfwKAPDOZLzWj4c2bTKZVq3QWxzFxSpWpFxQU7TpUExTx1B3NPUbTBtCw5H9ePHR8@efAMa3c3NzbhooydT/LDW4lhr0I5zyLQaOmgPFnRb9CSe5o@T3TgcT3eprp3Z8i1ZwoU1KAMGpOKzn6jjcSHLQvJ8ru5CPB42RFEB63xaDYwZqYSqjoFNtiXo6gFBTC@2YQggvnoL9E5Sby1O59bX63h/Zr1OzVe9jouX6nXRimHR@DPi8Z9H1lIjd0hXc/JLFy4lifaWs8dH7OWnu6fs9NN9dvBi7zP2jaMX7OXus1PczPz8xaMnh3sMfvvPTvbZdEQBH7ygBjuUQNfHZtPEm8HwhKssI8h7zmDC5U5sL87dT4w@@9RpmjhNte0a/YddblFt06vwWPvQHZ3gGKZFlxD1LQ/XW9ANOtCNReWmRVvpcPE@g7AN6NP2sc/bd1pW24KwEvZ9B5bp@ju6WM@CEgR56@/6THIlCS/LoaVDdK0VrsC6hOgGhMe5GwBj8PVXdEWp5fIIZktlgnDB88EUPN0/fnrCdp89ZntHzx4fnh4ePTthB0fHYH3@jcNnnwA9D09Ojw8fvUAvCvj06PHhweHeLjlwBNIqww3rX45cbyUKKgYnqjTPceabbqINbLOj3qjBs0uDNhW6LDqyUfpYRs96a7aiJWnkovqCGxlpqoDF1nePP/kc2nxmvsEZTn8qmNYfyC9curRpPc22KTWoLBWobyVRXaHZU7Q4zUf0JwzPcDdLtPU8RuYk84HTIp6WZTJ5D9eo4Ng336FOddkHDQmtAWwE5S9YKTO6eyEaTW4TyAqk1uw5eKAdT40vIhQWjPrQX2pSkohiYq0MAsXNB4c2jgdppcAB@B4cdJGsN@QBWCZw4AFYljugKnqIa0dYToQYeUcjFM8szx2@7A8OaFqYbQYOjwzqxRYETrzcqEgNFtxdg/v1e3TDBh/loZu/DLdpWRTFpfB4@0SvxyuGye89ApnIpxJpbRuElEHYtHGqQSx741f@oS9wA64TMtqey2LluMpOcXGQaVv8bpNOz7D5Eqjp0h3iPVbA81jKYoGtFdwJ0uJXyRMD4n1Es3gE8R4LrdC8bzyI@ehWioZYI0n3cvlL0O5C4NEtBH4RMABImenpNKmlor2jCMZpC1aOuQ5wJI7bvguHB3ZujZrmTASxaiv2pfX2bVwQOTnTT/LXKRJ2UERvzSGolTSV2XaGUMdJrNItCigFm11n4Fm8DGOzOaAZJ2rmIDQ2bJDa63JlJjWkw3yKtmOHEm0AFy9JtQFMeZ9UieP53HkgvqZX6gHnQyPM190hOkYDb2Kdzp0lcRLp0sThF1CEaa4cBz8nHmHC9U9pKjveMbyVq1CuPH50prx7ncSrubhY4Lfh@YsO8QeMiWlB9aB5PlqwOES9S9Q0/0oVd9TA2GINnpCWWMt9YNAP7FrQr3tYLwV@fLnxbXfc8zLvTo7X12UeS0HJJC5IdLuxqXRLsqqfZJLi1JhYAhKSnYAsyPqY75IkmIG8foi7W7AUSkARG@UI9tvnLiwRIsTPXWPUBski7o0TxR3Aj7MKraiYXqOJu1rC5ZF6FXtUTlTiqemCEhYiZ8wX0UkfshaPh5alUHt1C9zj1eBAft8fXGEldrx5@CBoj1dC@yDclMRyWLxZCsG6P9h3K8Dyxu0XAgt5Ty4HzBvJ29ACTg@YM7keCVbTrk7x9a2yo7oHYLDtxRGUAGgotZFNU9T@WbIxHiEeBjNViE5OH@8fHzOZ908gLsg97DK0hBhE2Gvs@XS1rWWTsFMDpSnoLAfKk@8ys6LNf1ZV5oXEWyIqhA6SFPQIhMX0wti2NeZST7QspELQ6nsSiD7lZrG78mWQWxWAb6APCMhOCy2UQWlhNiO88bHc8CJwQbck143Da/hphTVvu/E2tuEkDCi8Jsjo4M6SxeX3kuvHRT8drmCZb0aU4RZo0tDeQD/hBG9eh4CqOluCK4rFL1JcZM8V7IhPO1z4lZ7VsP/@DEWMxJVwrguHxLpQjgVqXD9e99UcWpCIzYCBKz2FJ1/RDB6@iCeX7XCBxqeNXmy2CQIlE@/nehjmCoheuykFl0XHpu1kOVDIw3VtnbCp@ljWcHRWwC4tD/QxroXOz4uH@aRA2q5MSvmHSYq3EjMp@TRfmBnfEyDnc7nMXbDnc@FHV/6@sHkbMi8/vf4A@vdTkO7EpeF94NzDZ0nff8oAK0jHl9b7FWYuIqg6C9qUmbxTYxTGD3Dh40KADB7sjFeezacaZ@M53BZD5y1SGDoFuZWHUBUOMsprzS3q36xODgXynemtfXh6vLJhIFw6eIOr8p86Q9ec7soLHZsScsJtq7Nu5nBoUzC@n6mPUGK0jWnlZjvabccXvPJcoSfNt4Vz0ha7k/iy26Q/1kCJ0PCiircc4uheaX54T9FK4aweHD7ZZxt0wl17ZixSHsrxkOxZs@xVCJAMpnEJbD5oD9/HbhF@gEPSBwlkot18MaJN/E7ciCKgNVfprgyxLFTIVm2@9Ntu07DxDI@k/LHL5OQDiEijsPtHB/FFI@vp0kx8QM4d2DGIlZQVVaao4IYDughpFgQvTXQPNVi4U8NfKbnibmojpRXS@S2JcmcnvWS/ulVLbjTLMoPG17D77mh42TrvON2LNuuxwZeNcXPy9g1juSzLQFr6A362qZYvp@g8yE14F9hWmjhXILhDN4WdyYypdBYpTiyzaT@8tMbiZKBOcxF3SMxxKdvo@1yIW@y8cr@ar5XtcrrUr9q1Em7y8xJlL6ElYujwAFpRkDF8Zr7q1bBNDY@6mvYF3W1P91uJrSGMtoaAy1NjaDlPdp99MjMahwoADoGJtd40oM5vOPwIV7Ph3hPVNi9jYpgsyZBjJVSQpI9oV5CGG9ZpPBmHY1oWYAalkgRt1h3TexKXPkqro4HnkI9ISEHWYtfWtfSRv40pTSMKEKRq1Xx0tgnONEwMJ4a464SvolY0rq5puHcyHgJRxZgkDuUzWcY9hYio2MtVrUmuahrNLiKBV3peUzS2vU0XfAKruSqN4uFSDmNIGybSNTTiBAh8BjTbgEmQ5u7Stg8Jso92DQ3chcaoPNonQwvkJdIU0QeXf7Mr2t9E8beBAJzwH3GdSxVDnELzAkWS7x2kwQU8YGy244/TDLitkhfKR5hZhM3TK0@B00pxohEmK8gE7h9dIjk5reAROVA0st3KRhA@zoMTSWieWthcpCUVKXlV8NObRouFoil@ND9wiBQf3UkNHOmC7tFTE6rVhO2ZvR4gzWnx0ZQcaKT9vSL9RJC@W8U0awHy3F@55a/M@KvcnyM1DaVCAz8NVAwHkiNX03A3TJ4GS95Kq8xIeVGhpJsqqCTTsKVVYV3Vc@rWNHAlKErOlYHH9oyHEvJ5taD0uc/aTJyAwQP/KvcX/K2Lkg@wnAn7cDZ9/EqigExaPCvWmsxxqWpbvR3eaAU@yGYyUJMxHh3Lm9iOV0qxB1OIE9DgcJyfqm2lPIWS0HyJQ3VGrmw/lFWhZOzE5tHguxhvVawFdSREJUozQYQb04ZFSIe810IgCCYyGvNrbsWPPBGRJyGwGGrNT/b/Le7qttpIkvS16ynSEjYqLKkkbPCPDG4BwlYvBg8StjlgqwupJLQtJFolQGqbPbN7sS@we7@PsK8y7zBX@xSz8UVkZv0gbPr4nGkuUFVlZmRkZET@xU@KF@QNAaempUV8DX6RX/HPCHsSOZMvOz/xnmA@lcaLd3OSQDzo3s/MJ1NyNIG7iHzUjfrGLBLVPUtDnD9I7MZOgW2dgfhgd3EMft@OE/GBwowUN@huUzSlowxlw763dSESr51/eEvOa5/W2OeDYKqq2Gb47IXlJBzcEUg2RKwmjiQTXpyfD6B15AXfFbtQ6xAhyytQt0QQYzN70anDskfy5/GkHdKpUFHtAfIVDESihPCih/vModhBiCYaWnHi0p8UnepwJgcaJDOPl8XNPFAXoWhNabffiyMhPSfSA0qH5347KDq0Rgtp9eNIU7si3/o8HX4jCBdGU9oLx/nLRb/96@Zr6HOflkuPyzGSXWp1cKn4@EnkYEVEMgnLJVrGrpSfOE5MN9wW3XABAPNqBxP9e@LN4DIYDgOnSjMGZwxp0RoG48ugU3Sc/cAqgQEXrAzNJPywRxfjthzu0KLLJ2aEl3CYF3UYcRh@MT@LurjNurK8A6VVpG2mrr7sd0BA43HSHUE7zAoLhAkQeqDQWTAhoiy5KokS6541Lrx2OcNBFFEDcU5iuglLhuFo0m9Tz/BJljMgUKIGiSobdlKYUH3tgQ/n4OI8BOAeE1HAIGBUSd/CwdFK8z@Eg9INMzp23/SMR6PfiGWFxD0Y92n0jQjMvcLFYrhTBzff1Buqsbfd/FDdryl6fre/976@VdtSG4es44ainCPVqjd7OzS6WG26aM336EOm2qCSGU5wqruHqvbx3X6t0VB7@6r@9t1OnaAR@P3qbrNea@RVfXdz52CLte8EQe3uNdVO/W29Sdmae3mu1RRzonJqb1u9re1vvqHX6kZ9p9485Bq3681dVAatflW9q@4365sHO9V99e5g/91eo6bQMGer3tjcqdbf1raKVD/VqWrva7tN1XhT3dlJNXTvw25tX7GRQKyVGzXCsrpBW1jUxO3cqu/XNptoUPS0ScQjBHfyqvGutlnHQ@1jjZpT3T/Ma6CN2l8OKBMlqq3q2@prapyT@w5VqF82D/Zrb4E0UaJxsNFo1psHzZp6vbe3xbRu1Pbf1zdrjYpydvYaTLCDRi2vcP0XV00wiFqUTs8bB406062@26Q54@Ad7B1c6uQPRBjCskpFt5jAMINAa4lIe/uHgAo6cAfk1Yc3Nfq@D5oytaqgAiwqNpvxbFQhEbEZb6barb3eqb@u7W7WkLwHMB/qjZpLHVZvIEMdBhmHxDpU6QG3Gv1EeMkjMatjODfP3anq26q69b4OzHVu4oBGXXMLk23zjaZ5EeFvY4co/RHODPyz@MFK9@anywDRJG@eyMw/o7ERkzb3tmo0I@tgVZko4YBmnWepUErxNJppbCK9JkLWdIKTi16rP@yO4GNqi8nBx1nYy@MiExfXOBw737g9RJ@vcIFsttV6X23RRrfRarn5u5RMoPG9EvoY/Fu5XN1GBLnHzhsHPy9eCN1fJgi1/lArOtlQDwoI5BTqPxTTN/8scJXndQJdDM77AGyOjkJRm5xClUJDIzs74l6KqEo@meD3vmYHLpgz4IvtFs5JYRnJmUYh/Rt@jV5kcoh9oNFZjrs8D5tYRqP/e2CqkUo4JAL/0xEJ@l2ushgGwa@9XCleHfb8xd5o1Mm5rinDeSe0D@zl3O8UPwl6qeKFdHlGltXOOi5@aPbdvISx@mdNMqX7pTjmluXwrzXhH9dgIzEfcGrKVfFhtT60zD2U4rBIyisd2gLuFdzJWPO9rX6sf8BurrT8pJL6/sZ@F9mCvSCiztKEd8TlPvHPm0@SgQSMY3EQSfo6QobnxcoYexOb@YoyniITXxzAc/VpwPM6kYQWshf@IF4nZuNxfxrHnsbh1/vVtxsH29s0dALbJ89Wnq5WHBt262Nefg9RD4dt5ahj5zSP0zqNk2JSskkLH5aUWPDsiP2ZgT0PGRE13XQaf0ScB2u3kbRkwkCG5oa4pGUIE71MADpkFAfguO8Yfp0rmZoBcommumjNmT/lJb5PayXmAW3MMphxr03xD7Ct@BsRtw3SDKRZjIPlEufS7oLHvcy2MRXlzQ0H7kGWYsbwsYRxszTgoy62n4V3Lb9p3o71YiimjJBX7nYuSUjcT2OhjF3FUCT7HccZ0QfAHD2MvnzU/EaPhzrAHYe788NJddIgMm7bkjinjg6jdaOPNORP62vURQ8f2ppeKpzyuxoplj19nGwDg8SkgVH5BKPCNZUCXLFxRNJVsgXsT4uu@iKciuAdgFPRHKvfiXPnNUdDqZj4IfrdRKVQAssGORGqXdk6HJPl0MaxMORMkOmH6MHw/0SazIH/knacBD2iViwI4J0oyVCFVrR9ZaL0r4yiIabdiKgZ/3QYgbmOd8ypbZjW3kzFv4ZIoHtnZj4cctjDbm4OAcDkONiIy681STv1aev0U8bVxaEnGbbPznNKzxVmqrgBt7D6Kc/LrrzRreDFVa6cNcUq3KGi6ifZuJ2w1NOWKbWVVw/CjIBzTfwPb4kPQKzAM5eeitVqmrNKWsrMOKBDLcUmnI6NmETL0utbtXZLKhYiMzH2a82XIRSBXgc@N9vJ13mMlJjnJiMuyjVYTY6Ch/je2CZj8tEh607YEHMQAM6DDh@G4MaPyRUmiIFA51B9ETSVe8CGIqgksjqM4gxiuHWLRFqeVq8s9nwyCQ612B8MJfJ8IKdaJkdRAnxoDOPu8kX11p8RyoO7NVtYzFtqjPKwXURlciyhy@N2k/ZoNKalo492E475/swtqg/60CEYhhdjHb@Q5rP@WJ9ImEU/VYNlk@zeeZqRgOyMWtifwFuhU2T@4CadBbAQlfAk08KqyhHzGh5dN4eO/emjssq9jFJeEk04LCkT8aVaVV@/Si4hqA4ZGjAF@6HdXLDNJtcDvYMVv6vR@FfM/VgCDTtBx0YmjYHks0DppPqQYzy2J9L081HIJxrUFTgBsZQoy0GaNVSlOfqpZidt15SJomMidim35I/XY5nUWEtRRRHj6tqJ@VYL1Jmg0rIODWqDhZaXVxiVeRuu61s3YxwtNKm2VpnjoR1SXsgiYu2BWTriScZN@3SIJ33Iv/YghPTQF@i49RIUCGPNCr3qzXGO8YNNwYd@MO7Ez0RpJdPxz3H8xluf0ZB50Rwd6rB/bX8SBjPaAbS9/tRjGK3cz6PTYWtzNPB7/VHfp30awrJPZcTD44wf0WG98egq5It7OKETy9SZRc8SX0bCsOHd6iUrsdBc4SQ4z8XNFCbjWfVUwkTwyTmMAJWdr5i/z9Mx0myZJytRISfpf8r2eGW3cmvZx@V5hUWjDwB6gFtPWVCID@mEHZNizqeVGxlOvpUhhuOJKijfvcViL4HxcyIRq2ESGBtkbpglxBuBndmtGB91pvkOxyAcI9BSsBXgjpkwx5/zPu6spVHkFSwFXqjys1KsqGhRpohDiIfZ7eRefvonY08I/AD65cfzuGUeI/AQ1zXRlkLZr@goo4QLmwf2eYzmkZhGsX6PZqFBAmhrmoaaTJ7dRg22/KFFkQ6zd4MrIZE52vjgLrhci4ac1szFpLKoFl2O24ElSHWSK93OsMH37GdZ@KHElZMzDEybGnIuhvRtpGoTlXBBZ8q8No6yxFT@vsQsL9@111IEXJtncha7ADaXMSsX9kDpy/wKtdZoTINxJkU9beqxGE5G54t3pN6tY8fcyGzzaN123e8aAguzrdFkudRh0q7N8DirOGl8UkyTpBhbmhEPYfvKz5bN00ScrrUgb2ut2XfocBvNIrspO6nY/u6I7GNSvIRFr5lorEgx7ghSWrHfj1rU8NbtI4iGKdurFo8YLQwZrZk8xkClyGSpdHcKMfdp3FP06BDlUG@HaBfvn1uJmjaSMyFPTVIiyCXoicDtcNqkcem8C@MLhImTFa4dpOyCc5qfsSqvXDhBkGEkCECsioNCdA4lJ7hRZ6X4iG8H6OZasBYqYySip/W4hYMN@m8JxlH59eGOtnhozQrlTxWBNLWQaFfBub4Fyfib0@tRa8pQbpCCRHwOKWyLboxNp3dv1Y@2hfIRBCnNydrSt5RHY1z1iLChf/Gk1hRr4KgqXTIhUUlBaPHQQLJAu5TeIJDtKlZ//bFwPKwbtBjRBkI@5/DzSJdAOO/VkqU2ikw7M2RxNblF2lxVWJciEUPJO8ivRVGWurxxJQCBYEzl18oEAWFNGXsoBTj0TpzzEojqPqKCa2WIJX3kqKiRneecdBBVZ3iyEstRmpfjeRxGYS4QWljMzxMhQmuW@VkiKDTRzcUlluPp/PZEOWhBbHhfKE5doXslSUPbc0JAemRs7YhyVFb5kuZgTnyy4iYSLX9z6vNSLLWUTiX6WAyPCuV06rNSIjVR7fJysmiiJNHDjdeaSCRSuHGE7ajwY3/smhIPeW5tQmObjMQqQ9tnD7GVusK@rfivoXrJTtlmjWHgxT3DzfarJVesJIKyfzsAu9Jx/ys/3lhjmGoQ0VcFcFg64@uSk/0gL1gzmOnRKmx0TaA9G5/AbGlHXfW@ub2diPp6MjN2RmfBeKVUKoGHT@Kx741pNU6S@iMvmdvrXgwG3vnVz@P3Jx4P/bjIfhCOXpgNdEA9QjIRFkfjnlwMARwoK3IXtB8rtvoX3W78BgYoKNF31GuSUwdDUDz/9K3Ny/smn/8wSD2//oIGon2/KCt8V76sMzUUo4Wi0rAIvswY5RmRBx@6MM@2iioGhnHZGDPRtOWurX/BBIKLTbizOHqx@yWyTs68CQaDUV59wM2/CBRw7zpdYHs7XqAkWaBgZOfei5DD0eZVcNkfxNyKkSXO6gBn5iVzzYQJC4/Q@PtBrzY9z2WOPmdoVqEmP0IzHyE8dV5lehlXx4q/A1jhQ0L7TrnP/PNcm@mUzkwzvRbg6IkwelzOz936JLK4fCSmafb93CDqfHSLHKuBmu7yUsCEsufu5Zbckt0SN3M8LXdBw5LA0Dgh5MrdSsDT7M8bFS8n3e7dBkW@BUA69p8@ILIKgCVQix/RE0G0/6VAYr2diici6xvc1XFz3EGBFgo4zoP22m9XuWq1qhbOHz1S1eoGPRQKqrpRVVv4sLGhtuh9A@8P15ZXVioy5m65X@jjhvl4rTYIBh9wPmqfjrfoldLW4DYGY2108YK3tpCvLLTWXq5XQu@ougGvfnr6@7//59//47@8qn75H7xs8MvRZ5upWCx6C@0vCw@vK3g/2vq0uHBytHD@abFXAZf9g4OGj@qTgh9ZjxbHJ05WZoHYVzYjNdtsDj6jiypznd@ZP/6VRpcXKtsOvaz@GsrFUTzGZttB7HsAN8oT2sGbOwfSO3lCIktAZziNp95pB7C/o/mGKEm4wAxUyotqxZzbIxqMzWCVKlkdiIeXrJcBXFqiQApwxaUZq9AfhsEQB@CXvOSV5jmOT7/9SUvzr/f5bdjbGE3V0nFOLZXUUl4tZTL8U159Tl/dBa8P51zJRruBTCZPKZFmAVaGKuzzOo@3D3zVTorcjrPAN/YAkolSwZnFCS5vN3/sKyP3rYU95x7uy1RyQsI6JhTJflkYXlO3fKEc15mEpw0vFFp6E8OVxRQqtn@xAvJDsQOIaj4TgrwYUZVQ9LFDMp4880X3tcOXCTFgkHX/9TbLPT7QXLQw1CbPia0Ubjli63n5irmxIr7QjDZSpP4IAdanyG6yxI6Ei9lFR4y8Y63kZooTdrx9mvnE1GEWTIxpuhT6NxVjAjHmjhNuYajdWrQdt2hXVKZvtSuxqjJp02/lxIqcXQwm/XPtrcC1Q6C@2NquRZLQowxI4EjI/hc3JYzPCUygqFS3yF1ZM9UZoekiCUPtmU4d7BZFcRQjgvc5R7L9NSXbrsdOIoYdhAcYKWvJ1/X7g1AHXRkzsXv@@ASXA/pdvk9tImozPs7DHacpjEddi3SRIbPFeSTP1JTs@djvnfl5ld0dNcf@rE7TFq18Ju2iSy1EBCYgAeHTVc9rnkFYWqS7hClim8KGQ7i7YDDTt6NJ32asywm61IiCjroCIUiwE1My@JroqxQdI67@A50QR/nG4G2VkXqI5ZEXhkYaUibuNcNidkN0HFNDXHas4GQcQdVKpuEFXegCE@0Z631pJB8gRICuO6OdALUnwupz1I/ZqRcM/cTkdD5wjJ@/V1EyL0Ke@SZKMUZyzJWn5ejCO2BF68jPySAQMjeZaEbOvVzu3nGob3PLxucRjvFtTfE9X/Xt/XN8fxk7hqiDYV8Gy9QMFV2BUVR1NvwnCN2B3yP8Zlf@DKx4nM29uu@5R5@Ph5@WcsfDr8e/u4yJHpLNLFtQWa3LNiOWlhWaGb184tUYpYUm0uDxMJnheKjEhSVGAkLEyx199j599Qih4yzukD/OCkESXQZMvG/X5wG8dwPNbBILL@vcc5dc0/m5V2VX0dzKv@hD@eDKL2FhNpV8Sk/7nHGXQLGb7m8X4nESes@WS0@Wy09oJ9QLpoVxcIH5thBenARTWkqE2M7S1HP8e4IbEoS4noZ@hT5OqZ1yq4m4noTaR0kPoVrMuR7HshWVKQpPUH6iMkdLhYeLa/P40D3CRDCviOVMXg4FJZaDMe7LYf4MR2eoxw8xrqWdQ4QjYWQgJiJ8gloAZHP3ym0c6hpxWWQ3p6LaROhWBkLd62Vjs8VwNCzoxZpbXKxgEQ2nmcGz0rNSWkZviGhCQhf0Ymrxviqvv3r6t//e@y07ya4vex/G9DvJ/pZdfZaVR3qgt8fm7TK7nn2JbKvX2ZlHe2B6fPq3/6Xy6z8THKTMXtK/9RUDa3WWXS@scZGv2fVVeigvL1O9//fXv1IbFmTHhqtYF1p5xYhVDEU2/SHzLqWrOlop29LFaFhhvyzAEAND2pvTC@yipsvPSnxKl9VGFZeBDnxlzFH0FM92WRO2FJKTDGNOQSsjKbCGCgoC0lhQdFXMdMNYbYB5IzTVLw@KqyHtAH7R1hy2Smu58SCExdCCbIuoA3NSI@3n5WG99CpjrTteZIxJScUsIbG102Pts8eV/wc)

Idris 2 [supports](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/literate.html) Bird style literate files, [CommonMark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#CommonMark) and [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode).
Idris 1 supports only Bird style.

I don't use Bird style for the same reason as with Idris 1: I don't know how to polyglot Idris with Curry/Hugs/Gofer.

Out of CommonMark and Org-mode I chose Org-mode because it has an option to place everything on a single line:

```
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
```

Space after `IDRIS:` is mandatory.

This line breaks psPILOT, so I moved psPILOT code before Idris 2. LMBM as usual.

Comment: I can help with polyglotting Idris with Curry/Hugs since I know all three.  I don't know Gofer though, and I don't think I can make a whole answer since there are so many new things since I last contributed.  If you want to pursue this we can discuss this in chat sometime.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter [Large message, didn't want to split it.](https://github.com/stasoid/test/issues/2#issue-683767328)

Comment: My main issue with making a whole answer is a little more practical than anything.  I think you are right about fixing but I am not sure I will be able to set up and test every language.  At around 100 there were languages that I was unable to run on my computer and it stands to reason that as the languages get more obscure that number has only increased.  A 5-15 hour delay on replies is most reasonable even in ordinary circumstances.  I certainly don't mind if you take even a couple of days to reply.  I'll try to start preliminary investication on Sunday.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Forget about non-TIO languages, I'll test them. [This message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46289957#46289957) still applies. And by the way, it is very hard to accidentally break any non-TIO language by changing Curry code. The only things I can think of are `~#`, `|#` and `TAB`, which will break Objeck, Pyret and Agda respectively.

Comment: It's been a while and I haven't worked on this in a while so I thought I would just let you know what I got.  Idris1 currently follows the hugs path.  We can split it off by using `length$show['\0','x']` where `x` is basically any character.This is because Idris treats lists of characters and strings differently, whereas in Haskell and Curry the two are the same.  So Idris gives 13, Hugs gives 7, Gofer gives 4 and gives 6.

Comment: However there is an issue that `!!` is not defined in Idris so we have to use a different way to convert the numbers we get from `l` into numbers we want.  This could be done with a helper `p 4=233;p 6=146;p 7=157;p 13=301;main=print$p$length$show['\0','9']` or maybe some other ways.  If that is enough to take you to the finish line, by all means go ahead, I can always try and provide help for these languages too.

Comment: This leaves the issue of type signatures.  Idris requires type signatures.  This would not be too bad except for the fact that Idris uses `:` for type of and Haskell uses `::`.  I at the current time see no way to write even basic Idris that is also valid Haskell for this reason.

Comment: @WheatWizard Yes, `:` vs `::` is a problem. Too bad Haskell/Curry reject `||| x = 3`.

Answer (score 3):

## 303. [Haskell with LexicalNegation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/lexical_negation.html), 14208 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa














































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p><script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script> onload=function   (){d=document;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,2][ (":"+[].sort).length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-29]}</script>
<style>body,text{display:none}:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::tfgek:eps>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1ute_[2]!!\0 ad4ocod"r"n;z c
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwNFoAqowoN4EOhms8l7qdvdbJHs21cCcdEFoABUE6hCowASaDY7JM2u1hp7Zz0a2SE/xlfWjGfl9USMd2JnLe/YMxH21wnHfPIPaD82Nhwb1j/QnnMyq1AAAZAt2xEbGwsSqKx8nDx58uTJk5knMxum1/3ZzyL4Yc/c3rTTc0dsZHkj1hraF9ZQYw@n7IFpe1kjLUkYa3fYGfctZ@QVpQjTGfNG5nDEeqbTGZsdi0XA12Cz97bdG1nDBPMsizWsnnsJ4WnGHOuSHTpNuwWQ2Mg9txz7jTWEsAxjj6ze2/7bEWu6/b7ptDw2GNrOiEKzjD0z4aU9bp4zs@GNhmZzZLsOBOUYe@70zH6jZTKKPhhaPNE2A1DNc0ozH5Jn7Ik79CzIwW1anueiZwE8zaHtPt59@vFCfD3FPjYBqUHPmixkr@vshW0NW4spDPbZ6cHBom@afaq6Dju4iZKeYbvjkXs4WoSfZbsdyzGZoRU0YzEwB8QcWb18Kp@aC4KwA3sItWmKWivOasYZ9xvWEIgvqvDSHnU1SHDqcoIz1@lNmTUBYIBjG6JZI2ZjbbFsKoUx4f/EarpOawYevCyAA3Ct/mA0ZSpzXMEDEOQOmTcwm5basnp23x5ZLdazATu3LbDxGFQ4O7eml@4QKl7lrEiIeAOrabdtTCJK4EnIbI@sxrjD3PFoMAb0PNayPbPRg2iNKWtZbXPcGyVYA8KAeOR/2bUcgZLtdLAcL2Y@CMGBJsCx39SBNnavxwCdc0QHs/bYDgZcoj9GbViEpdVCUPszcgEks@f5pZ/PeC4bTPds6HaGZh8YtWURDT47fMa8pjuEN/hiXN4K1oFpmiO2s8Oi@08fRVklIKM2bEgBScvsijEW8QPZhdkbWx7rm1PI2xlB42Iu1Z@fQoLoLLoRLbJoOs2MFMtkWAYaW54Z2RSDJlEAB7RaI63DN8eMPMvowPfZaALzaQ/Njt2zOJSO22sjoG3kWCPLDPhNZaIJHtqkPLZZOs9y22w7y7bht8AKBmSCEDNML2Thm4MvQCgABjp80xmeU8AWyE5QBLbH2mbf7k059MEAwTdZVmfbABHQ1AGykQcIBQMhzH/C8EZdIGzXvACQas8@R3FhBRIDaysJj@TWVpJEFspGnqXXtXo9zBUIBSTK5tk25JqDQmcgZ6CjkTf8wne6VHzCazsFX8BxG0qcB/KmgFIpJNU2fOEdxJAB8sYA4WKAvDB08DfAnUaoEC8HYTmoq1xAWqNFtAXpCml1JCYKFB1pAMkYVF06w6DyMlC9aazebJoBnoDAdo6BTMnrLJ9h@W0G5CqkGJBeB2Sw7nWQZTogoSMwqFId6lQHRHRgFh2A6uksk0J01dMYDmnTkBZIoGcgTQbcUC96Dr@QDipehyx1yNMwCjPWAtyMLBQymyaeM3JQedsQBsQyAFcDuMUAbI08hGPaPBAujyy57RPC7A26JtICagAZGVgNCJIFnAg2xAe3sZ3mLEWxG9bIbkrXErQq3gOGJY4vPVACgDRhJsMOFBhwxj2xQAIqIJDmhdXYs3rARSBDmia4kW2htaPk8OHYIw3lLHRTlnuBHSk1/7lsPBIRjSH2oiCvWtZwyDAudLZegoSJN2541usx9rUzvNognSwQrG3T7gUIUNMxR9QPwDPqQX7TebTbQ7dP7auPwqLnuoMVYhdE0yUC@sS9tGaozySXORj0QJ6DvwWEGJs9QObSJH2A1IVwrhwhSITpml0bAFJWIFftodUk2ouiQ@o0SOB5FIvMqNxLI5SHoW4hzQYuCFUP0zjjXq8I3Z3VZOlKsmVdJNGHdx3zXQbi4Hcm0B8KEA0T@nLqTBGLANI9Q6Nu6tSvWc/tzxeNi5fDoOhdG7uA3qU5hdprg2SxJmYfNA6G3boDHXcfOIbXINaExzueQ9ZynegogHI5hO4VCh2UBED2iCYju2@BPuZCEqzxDCGNwo0wa0yBlYlaGY3UMY7JAqE0aZFQ3CMT8uCNBTq21riJVMO8bYc4CDoEj3qrCsDlSqeGDmhyQ8ts8WioXSBGIf0IejsLiC5UgSYBQg3FcjzQdjyN2agWAsN33DbwGHXRoGpA0lk@TSo7ljzwmmhNTSJKI9/0z3vMZs3BgIE/6CeA1kEqD32s@8pmbyCw1/VYrzkeDqdsMoAKsPsQa9R0221g2jfWoAsgWL/FmtMmtEooJTKN1HJJAjUHC0UO3jYtiONYUOy9Z19nHQuoDT1yGzAlTp8VYDCgIhApTIf31o4JlMIiNAdTIguACVK0XVdD/5ZrecQjoM0ELR4z86wOtQhoXu2ZDOqj9gHMCRqBAywLAke0KoSPGUpLC4NZicr/2HKgxTSBGaGtQ/WhPrrL2qD7hzprVO7MZtMajAR7uCTFbCek0BwdoEJDvqoApnldafMB6GJzGEgQVfI5J9SDm@ckXFHRJz3LRBErBhjQpztWoMIyLlB60xvZQ4yLhdzllxhnDoOX8gocBtQSULsj2TAeoQRBoWg3uygCRyhkSMuARjYc3yw@@IWzH/aZ2g7yRmx0kDaSlgy8EI/VMFT49m4C0gY9hFWZ88Cocx63gDa9/hLIboBkrxX21ZKmBrLwNqB913GXQAViBnAxynwI1QUx4wlKDbMXMCM1F2@ujlBOz8a@2H9B1zkYuENoGVzoTFGS8SoLcZfLxymxoItQYNw836NCTxHFfn404mOuQQ/GQdTEsKWCPmmCpAAhxkcAIPNcnmMIYWr1BEvgd0kSnzMTdKGOY6FKag6nHAgUD3plyGjK7OEQxOAF9g286/H7EI34FLoCs9VCyYrkoHa/mLmGHL03btiTxWFGEz21V550YQ5ZG0cYQ9A1oBHFom0vqpTIn1KGguSkOxglKSn/lSEiRdKgymNtGLRAR3AAguZk6jRj8lwTkxNMHo/aeVkBBybkqhn7qjkYLWL3CvyQafrn0K7prcQ60GurKvyq6EeYYEBSwwBzCOoFNELQsguFVsNkb0F6DJk62aPUqBbSU9cyQV6W0wryEoRAXMLl1XgW3rBJDjXUq2EJMDqVnDqJOQLekRKUUAaPZFL0n@hBSh4PI3WGe44dmh5gMa6BKOwqUNGhA4gRMjboHHbTHtWFlnLvnq@vbJTLwGygRIHYbClh5d6fR9FAUkNkjZQQkYk2ck9G2DZiCpQXI19zbEBbAk4tV9jVqDuEFkfv1xJEArJKDnKyT1hRz0/t83FrsaId9MRIMrY60JXs5kguSdD589ZQXkfV6BxVQfmPIlWReTE9gb7BvOSLFSqLaEPLQ623LFAJ1XAMMRC8upREPKnwmzH03rTZEyoBd0Fj59KoAeifi5F6IIgSQifwG@2NlsqBYHPgcNiz3dNPyqIt8sBkw3aKcx49t2n2yHsTo8t@2seHD493j79eXwKjZzeKix5JO5PPYVc7nqgdZ5zMaEZxMwxjBvhRfT1sTDgfR5ZEMFPdSUhVmjahc5n45Dw6/nSRJKAJITkoB3Djd0Gl4XFA6ZIaptdd6IRZJx6HLIMkflymHjIfZuBA1DHc9PF5Nn7zBitvEamB8EfMemOTA/A9k4eOn07DwAUFzA9qtHmPSGlBC7UdnP@cucIxfXw@Rq15ERlSpUMs8/HRwf5xmcB2Te/c6vVUipL0RqBLmcOWBjzfG7csaVkcEH/garK4NkMc9WnCdSmBm805As/qlq2ADwBwiKO5TO31/aJ5XcB9b7Fs5Ks2Aw6gd4KwqFeG9aHmhyIawgO7uCaOdJf1ohQw66wCr6U9VhA63201s1lrO1MId1vNWZ6tMNA@KcW26@uNQwg691T00WZapFCrBfonj28g7pESCUMB1cfM6zGN8vJ6Eo5eVJtFveQejNDcnqW9IIknM1lJJqP@xKfW9GjMGYq/P7FHsZTCn7oCcSH33d1D45EfWUzU0QQGDRpwCI4907CNCw1ND3jEcXtux2VbkIZrh36GoDatLOZux3Vu1JCJnljUCK5cgPzF@RpzAH2N/YYGjpQqPFzlqx6m412ClNZzaSQSUYhAJSm@9sq8MIFcs3KfHH5jHzoRPZtKBe4UfYAEoTRELnQ1Q77kwVTISBP4LC1gsIpxo7X7AWpoGQELLQRdkHB3FrzUkySmllwafylKX3VvUPyVO11gLfDhrAWOEMkOnz57fPh0/8nu52cjI5ude8@kCjkgHOTXAF1I63K6YWvd4k0Ti4XgItA2hti8QAqMYYDiT4ePvSEIbg2jaByBFVzD139iX3W7TtRTFgtziaHqK6fJWegJNj4eVSSEgXarh4ORIV82w/4c@ac7Gg28YjIJrbw7bmgwaE2@aro9s5OkdNAx9HpJHYcuh0c4r@EtSwHIeFOLp@BzWqA6TGni0Oz1XRi80FIcigYW4@Bpsqpnd7owFsb1OmuoaAEHU2mSLRghwFg5GZSNBDC9AW3F068nmbP2V3Qjz/laTxmZpOxHm2v@EHejbcHQKQa9FZBCWXhlZ/fO7rEpSGmEtAgkwrQtsWSDfUGPgSJJk6U4zveJQ9ICp0lRVhCNXo9xEhekVDKbymzruWwShmUwTAOdVcWpNrVvjppddeSqAE912zRvEOLCttc0nba2JRw@sqD3fQRFTVe/ODtzaqCgn90j3HAhrDqtVfWaUmI3k2yJ@EoJuHeueMi7vgfwLjmBNenJVsizlnlTnLVMal0tlhz1B6LPUQfsyS4oUm9ckNctK9z2MEEyHJjcmoubxMjvkksmhHqYVMIfpFQSGhT0tMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQRsNpvBy8GXn0NyBAfdyPe2G/Vorh71Gpwk9QZARJpjbqKU9nB@cAS9Y8D5KKWhclFIs0sritPnpscnKSGRWHT008NYLYBAk/HBRLQTLLYCE1AqGp6D5AC@wtnS7myWEQf9wGmQIeGEkw@gQTi0aNABOQOJeUF2eUF4TuQzX6Rzx710EFrDYnm1YY/4HL87HuJint0Klw2ipw0eB6BR4UJynVb9GlaTz7LyxFQKGASarG/1XZxKAO2KRIFFRTD5iiGOBT2cqIZmlVJx4QTgq@zBHkixpsXni9Q@DqKApfZZdDRM7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVFn43vIBNlX7qE4BmIoMVbJolETOgpJ24fYr0guZbMPChr@5Kg@moCyUGDpPNsjuwnMUxHx8RxpQSrbNGoyDwbSd2Fd3Y2IgWo5VoAlz3wbWDrvvoioPrPrlUcmE8DV2UIkEuDK1SCvSrRa@rPuSJUkMemKDm8MYexMxqsZiuJcyqLp4GPhWoCqA8xFbxAXCiSrmMTkWRK5e4VAP6e6jse8g7J82hPRAk@CooBPxd0CBNRIDhPWrzQ6uEY9P1FOmXhzBotFDFjA2jZ9XUWe3s6qwVP7uOJjC1UjLLMD4E4TWK9bXO0B0PQHGrZooqyDalmi7WSo1yNBXdisXyag8yMhXlo7wSNzmtY1ELeCp2dhYFkgrqVJvdIcGbJAxFCQgFeLRtGGX0erGodpWH/BtKTYlHIa0STYBYLkejQJcmEsGjQuOMAGeiA3sCpISGCV1ceE2BBCStSWFz/YY16E6H4QjBrBto2TiDPluMh8ZAUjwsJd/w9GGFbm6k7@u9PB4otzh5h/rSYMqlu8QxPUvOGYb4/e6F2u67IzP5mQaDJi3UXUY3oklVhZ6QQjgkKvYT28MmbDqWO/bCM41LJ0Axd/A97Y5BWPpWMwngKnsgWc2uy6KbDwA6C5Z5sCvBFSuVr3v5AFpNDb4oRFErwcUS0C7InMQGuYimJnxWRickuOjx5@azucFrLcitRGlYCjOyO447tFQgCaSQyPiDTIWkChMWJYc083VjXUKEUpeGA2/bAol40HNNoi0X16H1oEE/lB7G55Dk2GpJPZAfbRCPGq@LodVKbkm0OOsOu9BDQGlQEhtBbfVFQNL1Bi1tNIGkUgw73HAgH92B0nnJWoZh5JrZdtEPQ64AYnehknBU6sAQ1w9SdQhURCXv82khf4z@9OjRPp87oc4Wu1ecR6v33dYY9Eoxbjq2nE6C7QM/2Y7bt4EMfvo3571j1x3xUT68rJqZ4YNmuz/umTTnszgtszZd0224PZoKWpd0Fn889MyeySeh/NDdz56Arv/89KSsFUORkuZFf23eOA@5PFtOz8PwmiMts/rLQx5nTHkzK2O/5RujoZgRATkMGAtTNKgj338b/f0mhWsowj@P/n00QwNdWcwi0GvgKSIWKCKapqFFj/C80lPX6L9yDBbE0ykeVxxn2F7pBvlfjNrtOe80eZ@rKJp6M@8MeXMTtbkxYhilLI@E9mpzccKAchQnMFtbjCeEV2Bi0LV6/griMSgmuEoGfXsP1ScYm6Amzm3HLFCkB7gYQhIal9hYE3RN78a0BbSpgcpjS5ENaifQhyVRc5E2k0xMcZeopTiuWJr0uPR0YWhPsyc7Fb5gjUOnIR@1Jfnk@2YdQOxUSr410apomFM0GkQjqIQbpKBi0rL9jaIGRhgezalLlKQkeUkYNUyMlHo22d6vJT0iQpvJZ2eTj1LG5zD4QJuvzXvJjlXC7FZSi975PHSzC2KDxSfzJIN6GDttt9dS@aIX1D/jwyWsCGFqEFidkcAHH3voG5zZaMQiDANBXIZs1W7AXai6ys0IIeu2ABC0hiv29jxx8ZZVoQe70LxBzx7V2LU2cutdLPxoPHQW7eC4SjkcmlNPEpYqZbZ7/PFn1VSNQ5D6Ji5k5XltTXwzStCDQe9Ba1Vwob3NyB5Rx06GBTaWV9cAqQmteQD6AINnUGJBRqJEiPpb6@2sLG0LBp4xCzH3pv0Es5Rrrd0zRyPL4bzFVxNXk5sv@4hsypT9fbGGUGQpWmgBRdPGMECxxE5OH@0fH2vAoV4suo8LMkVodmazC/rGqkL7lAwXvsg@akXZR5hGwVG4BE0KBhN1kR6YtwTMDcMJyB1FQccaxsBTwbWUJnjT8hUl5AqXIBBaTTVHRKMAWMxSoEwErLgU/@cOHzkJPIssyuJESSB37F4RaGsr2tixX2se9BukhkKUKB97kolseTNG4mtTV4h/hnYf14JhyERaIJShWmUbIN0otszK79gX1ZRaqMU3Wa1W4iv8kBB1ejK5FeabpqAnXw4jASlwPhSjsvaCEa@fA83cYiqOnw48Kwm@BWSH48b0ZiuVNw1ZCZBV34AHD5QXkVxiZMpR9E2bSISQJdS8RdO8vVSoWM9pkL1gHA7F8REIyoPLkDFeSrZRZrqi@JhxQC/MIQ6di@yZ63l2o0fWq@2ezS3Bgs66KAgjIPmUCWdXwoZBdMP2DO0MK2NmsswNgQUlKJw6GhhJYcnII6awKyQmkdJAKrK3b9FDZpsGIzaQ0WKY0/faH9OCfHzsArKPhQV0WOcgoSHMU1B0nEmyP3ibX//FED4wSF4s6LzqhRxOx3VO2zl3aRUpcNVTmp5FPTNI3T/v3UzZtr0u/cxFDXDgcY1V2Hn9Rpt@lkSgxRSxTE8eNE0vNGyoTjN5TA@asV@S87xpyly2Das9djq0polupr6@JaZayFPkdqNhr4oKREBrM/@5JBrISmx5hpbRdL/14AQPdIsgP/mYaFb0RasmNkd36KRGkEo8/@s3W0D/m7XThf4K5zMDRx00Bawptb2yskRSfKGf5RXLp93HPdskwpDrNpBNcwhFMnuBYzloWtpXVdA3@rhQIWoceBN/QBddw2Ycc77O6D@XZ7Jsqc4Bud1cFXfByotnRYtKMFxsERG4zmVblIiELK8Ea8IXdkIDdxS4tyPlm2IxYmZe793xaMx/QR2@tRLtAX7XtU0RM5U1G7oFA1KzYVtrqnxono9brjo47wRqcW5J3FnpaWVZBa1ELDLX0bm8@LyAQ7sD3b3/XBVt1r8mL@lxG1d4ztgbqA0a27f4GzWE/pochj3@uyqKLXYqBY7VVLN79HNHThTQgVGEjUUSLVjVENHsBTL3zMYUVaHuh3NZYK8AEqfcjMdT6RUL1oPB6vQ4PqX0hcLy1BOtyemxbOYhya1kVT43RwUWdrO31Cp0V3bf7KlGK@RcKcyXmTvciBqslFIa6wLXiS6W1tyM@tghNcc9czhzrWHxGR7@4sSqeW7RbYi23HR7tocNurdKavo2d7O80E6ZfkJ2FfYySrZgIIr9uBq4lksBtzlCW9QVbHUHmcZtQNHSNsQnmruKWE33Er8rNYguDIb57/JO7c1SrO4gn9Res2dCV76yR5ibdcRZzVt49dL2LPpZTtjzpYiOmr2l/vOtwJ9PDM8P3sbZnt1zPXZCv@sI1BkCFfjvcp4O09I2HZVm2cPuNWLIN56YVajZ67i9XL6TNOFnZa2Ph20U/eJ5VyEXCCldv0VI@RqQ6@jiuVK0nyeH57dVEO3/GqLhbMi5ppddJqnEos7q0sHYAFcEl5fsIJWnlFqSzyGuyBjXci7Nqf/8OXqPVaT1e4/BlDRqUPAwQSEPjtGQa9k/T26Z9bm17iaUboDdvq0Qoco971nQX9HvjSplRkr/wBR6KnV3EdXuja2xtXSscdR4ZeE24jXjjLsjlRLF2BRLALjqgHteglhvxODwTlhjV41va4WJCaN263ZtZl6oDUABH@Do@Rk4nqHjZoqOMx7M1ercAM05Xk@y7sBv0m5rDjsM@VA5lL9FWZpT0T2LvmsHTXyQh5Zn5UwqlRI6TGgpZ@5l3WAqHaR9ZfPfuYzJZ5bzLC4u3w1DzuV5EFnCto0rRZCxamxPkQuFpGM71miKv3eUpg3X7X1ITYFQbdmojYFySTa862rshrojdqew2eyFh3MejfaqeQve24jhJdAHx83rKj281nSn2lRxNbWPK13zr@tncEIrV7flgtu5cVqIW/X2VuuSYkJE1/La9tpWxzVUt2H1TP6Y5DLr4BW09Fp480JDrALjqjFfK56t8UcWhNJgCsSyWzBQ6Vp9i17XKPpm69XY8x8rI01c/K4KnlhWMznZt5qrIgxskAsO/s4tToeUpZHrwBBrhAaEOFTpoYmq8F0lgf3lxKVEPuybHYufUbFOUs7mLNBMh4/sZs7lsxdFbprThGSzGebVLAGN6tyaev5zKcAn0ybU67h/@4zbQuNv4jToHVr7KtvYm12s03W7TtfqcoP04G1V4wB@HPEzRdahDlh3umgjNxjM2c6H6dlze7270BNFIxeUrtteitM@7qrFLWEfBHdqNiBAPG6dvzNHXHagY2Wr6Vpj6Jc8d@QOLJXeVkXt4VwP/10lQ/3V7593EmntUB8o4j9/Xvi3ji07pjsaDOhRH/TGHv1QUpU2Q9@mN7W5zQtZW7rDjvbG7Tc04akJgxhadF8uYhr2qNnFTeics62O22h27duQbljmyLHPk/6sD3@909gVKWMz9RF6az0byDucasgv5XD4CT4OV1W6mEDi3VrgWKOvLJuko/3e6sA8b3p8QhRdrIhzwqHWyHeFF2k7ffH12B7NgIaMpIIZXr4ygY5VuAuzjJWaFW2@mIlhYa6xkktJSUeFXLVSoPDoK@eX5gzoQk0sneY/qxAKl5IwChm8fAi5hVERTRDaoalb8J/jrzlrqKWdnNMdd7ybApPP2LdARcOf1dMWZCQdmrWGPst0xGMVmY1eEndPwrMOOtfYWruskl27rkLx9J5qujY86vCAqhuvnEPr2QOP/zK1vXI1ThhJwVh8ccmQ02a6fDAtKqZltfkqCLpuUxH7Lq3Tgg6iNnFNHyfRUZhzxYsLLsftgFBXe2wW2Y@7Sm1Zan@0vPqDPlP9/KnVMdGI@7E9QivQJVxBLLvMbulW2F8bm579tTGUbBWz4VEQfCVyGD4zAN@WwHtiduzmJ3MVESApCCxMSPljjv3R62ZdXHZtD22oAseaiSlkOc7EyHV1GDcsibk4dR@cgjFrQHx/5dLYy6bX3cEUt6FNybVuZt0e0SyreK4aOq6yLluLxOW4Pxh74rEcB7LSCs9C98/J37u0Abj6GkQr65q90fKZ6tCUK2hholOcOVdp49@we26HfSOfYqC0gRKGyvkSxnkI3fMzNA0aOks4kfK@48onTnSoQ16w11C3VpqptmOP1s/mjEZoJuQ/sTC858CtD8nH@Ks9@FAI6ulyijy@Xdef7Xm@pX8Hzjtxx8Omhc7gIJPwsEDkau35Zs24VcTFg1guw6O0tas30B26znikDsfO2l4ht7ZXKLJJPhdiAxb72v6T50qYG8gM/DYt1ILB39jrTWeulTYDC0xmO6CIrZaj87H9scQjfu7SMdkg35JmFw@HapK4fuQuG@88mw6t0Z0HTCD8x/1HVhNXDm/N@6n7xHVc6I0GICj7xxY/TGDO1mN5Qkz2GLfLA31at2ZzQmBXdEJc2zAHVgPqtzdz3aUv4oAfmSNzRVdEc4M0/gtct/KK3WtYw1c06RdyrxrSziP0iTWhscVqhuFtUB01m1wlxvm4uTYyt2LjDVzX4b8kbVPw0J@slyrQFdDP3dfKNbTwn5sXWDo@my/q0QU3FLFa/LSLVWUdWg23x3/XmCU5NjcLMIe25SUf4@EJ5JfLMBW0L2@tDNleK0NmQyPQZC9Mj9bplw81ZiD1yQdYAXXNYdPFlTDhWGOgEzrx4BYxHWwa4LYDDSD8BCSW2RyLsxdvQ6vXb/TpZ@WAIVSbx1YDtxs16JiQkTm5WZl8ZkickRAy6gpOFvDFFTbqHIs9g9GIcnu3NTeOmqeqPaAfktQrl8vJXkd1bKv5xsRZM5foNZubnguHMiefknPFXHWoGdEsctKkLfRLW9K89RooND1LHXWHMOZPjtZNb/vntyxZDxn3LVxknl@FWam6ul6XCusuX08PhOvQUsXZgSBLgnMEuX6o7q7UPBE8/B89/GoSOuF6LuOfaQKi6/YVfEB@PHTE4y4c@Mz1Rm17cgR4476DVeIEi5WFJPDgLQNdW6sKAbXnjHt89qETMr3qt2g4ptL5taraI3E9slTLuVDphLnJzRK5fDdZchcPQx1ZLVUcsIArDepjf2NZEE08lyyghmUj2nvqSU7YSS4jLECXEffSlwygb7kjdeDRMznwnh0@PjrVBp6@tH/a7eJ@jBt63NyJDUY@FZqSemUOQ@ud3CKtZXuj5MMTXd17fKhhhBX05isaKjxwZW7usXLeUxw9aibNlaMgDLVGyxXET06fPI7P9n6y2F536PYtJRy8d3KSwL0tXz1ZGhxOfQCto@1OViY/3Nd1ZQn7PndodXCV9FyS0ypIpxaMRoEZP@EHvtyqXDXdgdU6nQ6sz6DzRAnu3TH73MpCPjUv7A62QlZYSShqqKyg5TJKyDgbBtvWMHiuqs9ze4DSskmPJH@sNEdBzSGdHKaXaw/rVvwXtRiWEpYIH5ZIT93k1pGtQsvodNGVNL2/L2K6rq@i84nZhnpl2ZWVNR9h2fpwz724w1KyJQYvauCljoCrVPtWU/JttQ@iO4k/OD0vPMHZWGkGsw5A4J1b2uAvLWdqOiqtZa1TL4qQGo3a1kb5hnWHBanAwucCD4ReusYXWNWzWJOcyi0Znw5DSfb2Hh7eluBY0HJ9rI@fPmfPTA9PN1kfMYyxdQeMZ5rRKxXnrfBovZXLqa0hgDLWwusMlrfnIjsxhy3XmU5uX4Sjza3YtdNhxQEsfKNIVs@e2Mv6qiaf13q23Mzotrz5Pg53OqcHh0@9EYDef@df6HoqRWca4VNP8ddbasZv4CyGLnOKB@WFg04PA9HQRL1FAw9l6Wj0sTVBcxQ@G7xkUM/35xyPnfCJsV5C7Pnn2@r4RidP84/1jcWceFxR5k@OD2/r4hua8FwxvhcJ4r59yzbEliMICHZhiY1OePwQ6D8Wbg@UCATuP4s55bKeLbD7eH57EaSbQjniQSp0@F/41N4sKDNNyc@9yjavxI6iYlG/xl1VclFmYsdXcIojP4kQcsIz1KCUTD3X2eYIQjb9/UiMztJmbxnpUCC09WwK3rRkeINoSWzUAiQ3r54dPts/Od09fX5STdWuZUVsR@S4OQ7k5m9U/SjdkoEagpBQN/xcUtrQ2IPs6Jxv1L08v1wMSrZQtPJc0WaFku9jms0rx0kmaV9eUr0G/FSZ50ahIGjRi8P2S0w1JrZVFvl2th6RVN7koGXKE2qxyFLLMh6YngfFEuGLNw1QKEunMZRnLI6ShBbRcd2WyNGz2O0fP8eD3cPHz4/3mY/gjI0u7daoWy5k@UmjKL9UC@qpbdMSf5lFRZIo1FW5HD2IAmGiWpQVaTcknfIJnA/RfOrgPkqReovFNgk@UDAaVEryv34zeR3V0FpNgbhRH6koE5THCOwUdzj92Y9b/BRs/1wD/zqNYZ8aK@0fl8TuxRV7F5Gi1FQHqy/VoFOnaZticNz17KISiQ5BB668pCOJFo6rUegECX5DijhNyM@IGMQ/ORenPfBkIBizXdi4R5Hj0MaDeuZZGVdK6XAqje3ijSHA88ykk9gB9bEz4odhiK3zEeAjLRAxCbZJyPJz2@VQxOjOBrByw@rYDvMc0CWtUZG9Aj7DqYUi3yirqpXojSQ@aH5VjNod9XuhiDdO9vGSZ6Pk@1/5brJTYuCepB7C2y@Jtza4f5m7v0hiXd88/WeWfxgJPLFLYM0zD2iO9A5djuLwDckzYuEhRb7sZHYfquaCKI3ReQ78VwWRO4MTq34GFQUsBrUkNiLz/KxhLYZHhhWTSWQjXKbRyPjSmnBLiIWjw3LZXEZPApLqhQ@Qzvrt4C4vDlBRisD40oU9KL9sAHvt7DAZVROrnCvx2kxuOl@k5ZcBopsQV7rsInJVBmkgySwFhFVEMuhg4rqCSVEeRfUoiqKWCz0PhWMPhe@OIITMYkAsTiMLD4@d4C05o@HUPwKvgTfPhHqUTQFI1aHfIZciS2Lv7FN3BCwzt2uY751FSyDey@HZUh6/BYpOnkMe1G62ptmWL//AedG@NGz3HFQ6tdhhhutWfoEgThBEUV7GstUv2NnozKklOW8yYNMfCpYNM7MD7n@W7KzgWV7u3ZvnjsUWTw1DYrEHJ46LOtgBFIbFjKSRTuo5ZVakTGZpkUSJRDZQHDwN4S1kB6IJxETTsl@5A293b//wq0fPTm6crUUxo4vRQJJXduJnqpao1gJHNFys@Sp5eJA8efLwwK@IGdK5kAQGfUaURF9XktnQCkHOTHUXi7YMw8XSrcb4Bd/Pt4hv2liHGiW6gYee@oB8yVxOPSCj98XMjfwyamWz61CawUuGQO/xHUs3UI0pV9fV2k7lzIlEb3LCkobwRUTbwkYArjNvazOJzH6zcFiw4La2U7xnxgu3xfTytihvpvGIF9wzOXLPZ4fbCI9QQKi8fjYgIiUt6Udd2fqOuB4@O4LJ4LfJ8cNgwkdghBDOpdZRPATq1L@YDqXI7AA5cXZaFwY4Pbsh@UeP8DPU/KOeguPT@LEhMUUSx5DzjGPiqrpJcaLR2nhMQWlHsBJs3XFsPjxFggaN@tqzMQy0nrkDfiwtrYE8snzXsQvi99GYL6Za7KvjPsRr0@PYovkokNwqJAZKRgNUuf4EUkKcxjaJ43l3kF8Vz2QTBdf6rWxsomhda9KyOyDbY0oCJNpHul5jwYltWGg6oc2JylRns1pY2xQ/xn1oYbJ/0LF9kxkCZtXUbKdlTWLRy6hSrEH@6B@9fHERVeRlvETHB4rz9FqL5wgG6G/r6yWJORKt0z@kb5m0KBRuSgnwWwTMD8Dx78QoFLSuJ9HVRmXUxU9Gw8fgBDUi1u6bAxYbO/yQII3Ra@ws5iToVBW1ws8Zc1g8TkMkeFCAxihlm1y8/46ZzpTFkmVgAvT1nBY@3tgDVtU1rQZuykRhm3hXzR5oXHjghiLBOBeSFAlsGVkIBg6AEW8kGmdwSIPhEp6DMqSjlpYE09UdNGx3kSZUala5x0JXDs1rjnKhUBQVOi8VCwy476Y41JIA9oac83V5oK7Y0A80gwGtJkVmgvymxItQvhGOyCfiJABAJxI6G9A/IIABrNnJfc3uEL@xfQfaCp5pUnx@elDPK0mZBScKdIZ2C6eV@PG2waBNXEgAzTQ5FzVa4mO0jzEZHhVV50cW4ElGB9Rg5AWRGgmTYfECzhlv6vparhcJRS1AzAx2AGLbRd0Hh2ei@Qt8S8KWC/uf/Qyv@JRjm/dz6XrvIh7Npkrwo5eyLMs@2jxT1c2qkU2VH2zWTHN0JjMzmdl6dGF1243DTvJMllmaZZLJLSP3@nyg57a@qGqvJzW5mi8nzmvPztmzZ5@/q79T5MnFVD6Lse0I2zt6K@tQgEhxmxUYfpd@6O69pZ81o3Q5CnDPzvDqTnlbTiar0Rr8U9BL@PBI1YpW0e7X3r1TqttQpsn0LII34rGjB/PAYoahnNi2nWRnA6/Vgq/bZTV@p2uEf@LxmMqEh1rlfqw/aZPfZNfqdMb75pT725ExPg5GIu2Tb7x48QIdL@jD3hyL9Bw68/Mo1s1shBkp489@snGduHpW3/mzb/WT1gY@jvDx3esn6D7Rsx9tbHz08GEmkwAqcfezbzz7@u7ubuZRIvusmr2fUVMbO3/6JxsbhrFjJDdqnqfXotXz889lI5WRtT/7UbT@7NnXPA@rBT9ppoMTf/Pw1VGnOmdv4HPeZvhP7jetkNtEd6P9hhmRNxFg68iU/uoRxlthmbSk8GeD6ZX72//t@0evI6NIxUi@GMJzFHkdyeUj3AkOeEv7bxeRSmQHo@WuI9NkuVwG5/Z/@/eQvvJVgIMh0x34qWR9WLlppKKWKcnbSCUHDt0wIN//65vfvGXa5wGrwkfObBvy/Rp8tuizI@E5TmoqmVyIrufv6fcYc0bdkeXiw@YPBx7MLDkw6j6uxuPxmqbCR6tToqSuG2c0YRNmLZpviQTeJcZ9WMhvxifCB8JeRIingKmIr7hbeBCrcY8Xi/FeLPmUXvxjf46lSG7jgfWoUgFRaFSMrUqcPhtnxSInf5Jt52XXfYAzWtEzOcpesseC2BU5lTfkRCLxoI4XJrMJ0lSdRGYEZJxGLDJH2QibvbGwV4T5ydgszofG28fPn/9vf/6DP/8@/f2Avv8Jj7xyWnY7ucWRv6jwD6tU5MpQvjqjlwcsVcwX88k6uz6LbVUrtWOmpz5@G82moydYRorEzhR/hjMSfCoV/PHRwLdKhPtUuGvmJ0IqwQvFmCVZHo8JyeQTNQJdsLAMUqsXNY4bxy/8meCHVR9ANcnGdkGuVYyscQRVp8tUcQXW3fSYGxElug@fDfijf/jcx8lj4YO/G@TJQyjqks9GgMrtnzlcpUi1mqxZNVBkWcUH8mCjuJEv5ooGVMpqwKVVoCMXYWmibWt5zQDx8a66wY45r9dY3P@cxW/9PNe0unCSw8WvqrqTiBT5R/hUJBa5gk/t3Vb1HbCuyLoq2ml8R61V4gIjeGj1B7W4en1d1b6Il0rif6cSOEv04S4oSO1aVXe@AFjVm1A5UPrV6l/sANj4TnWn7O7RV6sjidXaF5XqznxakfzBgzjK2AcAoLJZY9GMG825D5gSj2@q6kZ1ZRkAcC3GYFQAFXi9c125ru5cX@/swP8O/V6LJ/he79z4p8fssyLOLJyazVk1WTlLngm2qcG7lqygj5Y8A0cFnhAPuiEpokKDkiJbbCsyYPp2GlzMKupbRjqZnXyU2wfVqFpTcQRTVqt6LltTuaR6qbGiys/J1vM5RUNRVHfbddzaprGXUuTl@y//F/yevf/y97Hfh2ZZkCLJLRweFPgoAX6eOOzJkyf4feI48A/fJ/zjoA96PEE/h/84PIYfJ/DmPtgcQCgw2cjn5HpcnxossiPntlEs/MKNTzQa/ScvjcJ2lI@gcQvYSw88f2HZ55/8wqqPFHlbwHbe9BgvkxShdg91Ae2ngs4r/Gm8xr/Hb/Dv9Qj/Tpv4d/wa/9jpG/w7HuHfkwb@PfPw7/Q1/u028O@0j38PX@PfkxH@Pe/gnxQpg7K9eT/VSzVT@rl@Dg6bpYYs1U119RaOBFIWS01TU5bqu3oLXBb8pcBlp9os1WEpJ@XoOgSCY8RSI3S14dGBvzZAGcKfjYvA53qqySCXHgDlV93Q8y0IMuVMqsIQUn5pgVqs6VpKy9k1PCC8KteMQp5pSGGtXn15Fq3hyZNGIcMaU2vj7CWLeKBSlyLJs7MknxxgRqaEZ4lfX9fr@08f1etJFEVnT9yj2f/RUT/8uva/f@Q@OXL7LvwfHR09YVYl/iCuPoBPuRLfEY/7kUrp/llRxXbri4pIcuf@WSWtojsXh9ZvoF/8Az8ziPCsbJxJUQaaymWJ9KHS5UXpskSO4BUc9VIQQUTjDvAsCT0KfEq@QnUJn4tL8sQfdF6@OAtc3JF8cXmG4wIY8AX/oHCGX/8B/u3/d/0/ec5i1RroN7Gr650YfRT8U5Sr66tr8VtRYjHxEtuBP/SAd0xydV1BJ0W6Alc1ptSU62vuB78xZYcDrGAeOxVKPIsIjT8S5En58p/YP@wT8xafMzyj2pyt1J@dTVIppdTwz8TFVSrzLS2YKiW64WSzUdVrf/ojOvn4vkKRsplSSd9i/MXIGKVSxn/bzpdKef9lMxYr3PxUUvf1HCg4mYyilErwct8Hm4LXAGwewPovWYBqeWaT2n0pcnV4RGcCg5jIRhQsERcMsRQdHY63UETlonzvXkzcbnl/V7l3zyik3r4NfAYD8NLnvOr1lj2s19E//fatXJdp5byQhfdU/u1bkGVRxR3GnuLlJZBRTNXZR0aF8iy4QyDENgQzPWnMsOianjkaDWNv7EFCRnMWT1boboFUyh2eRX/6vW996yxaLsuqTL4ZHQFgLiy7s5PLVCq5DLhzeaCUvHnFr9noxAu6cr2ZlDk1mLwZjYggPb@tcNkYxXDo4dj9CjRwDz/s6jpC1c4yWSUG0lUBRes6gn/cWy8UuD/L5GL5eEH8lTcUVgEdgP/h@DQdz2xtbz2oMfqbLPugSC5dWWX9unxlFXGa77rUFDfH4f436969dAFomk@VzqR6/dHu6W69XpZlGbtD@EFPEu4SXlgzGEarVOHZQq2K5audRaPF0gNiDj2fZZFoScRTo9BLsHyByCDZbdzcCmWXdDH435AMeuKPJOaCNsATL3dns@@zx7t7@6cJYwdUGuNgdy9hnDx/GNHxNTt7p@A0vh/v7z46eg4Jnj3e3z3Z//jws/3nz8DfY5ezjy@Bxe/sGXYteb9kL6RXwzemZZnW2LLql@Px5Wv2yrbrNhC2N7Zt2@0MmWfVLcsaQDT/U4Jv0/bMV6/M4YA@7P0Pv/P@h//d@9/53vvf@c773/nBT7/8wXfg@2P4fo8/v/fvCln8/emX/@J33//274Dnf4LvH8H3Jz/98te/yb/0/sfw/S8hvz8W31A8/pUA1i/99Mvv/@inX/7yb8D3X4nvb9z8/spPln9/8O3VX0z3/d9dH@d7/x6@v8dh@XG/99vcD5834v82j/fLv/H@1/4D//9T8YfO33n/a3@MP@Lln//Gn/6X99/6j4aR/9N/@/7b33//7W@9//Z333/7nxrvf/3f6qnwz@@@/8Ef/NUf/t5f/eH/RP8/pt/fu8v/@9/453/xv/7F//4Xfyi@P4HvfwDXT/7iPwLD/u0f/BD/v/8Hf/tHP8T///lf/@0f/Orf/tK/Icdvcsf//a/@Hf/961/5z3/zW9/9q598829@9Sd/85t/8Ff/xy//n7/@n//6v//9v/4fv4Wev/mTv/qjX/rLb33nL7/9L//yW1@u@P3O2t8v7@D/5T@Cz93xvAucu5TrQ32@/Lnw@ftQY5YL8Alw9z97/@u/CAz@a4y9/86P0YoTviv@f2zoFOfH/O3/Aw7jZpkxJAUu@P7q@@98D0n0PwCJ4D@g13eDl7kQ/vLd2QuQ9bcWEkWs4nznmTfy8S0YYWwVCqIDDYJ3KOVPv/yXPwqy@MV5qHNhkON3UVLNhX0XZdz7H37z/Y/@6fsf/ub7H/4S9mZqppDYTaj6@sln6ALV7B3iYcTcXeJBxM8/h/wncZoqVeP4xj4XgZ9//rk0eZtEs@EHb8H3c/LiH8aDIIyJID9M@KOlajgOd6Z85yZ6vw1njWSIY7ZxUgW2fD0lm2aTuD95iDNxfBIRI022@Hwi/pIvBk8k/Jn9z5wTicUxDv/gTSu@kxwinciCO6UsZBOfTEKzl6R@EIbch1aRKN9MgWEJJpP4BEak4IAc4hD0MM7K5XIcE5Y5PvDKUavkGaESj5eh3Jiap0nU8whi8pCgQMpy/JjVt8oTnjCO8Co@OeISeh3LuiHH8@VHkGF58oghLAROYF@@LFfy5UkFwb3j9IhP4g8JJwRWjk8q7@C9TDDjOKn06B2gki/H45U8ZoiF5NWTqPNKylLhqOxxFhd1AE@aoX3A2Eeynpf5isYGEozHxt/4LPZ9WmO7D@Fn8S1RHPr3nfTdIoJvUFYiF8bD75OqeJ9rjxgB4KqqpmkMvqqK2DyA4AkHFads4RHnEOLEEcQBgQewIdZFnOo3Ti@Qf6S89cGfeEXipdnc3JQiFTktH9EKTxxG7cPzIr8q4y0fGhWZnCvI6G2R5TcvnbX5jKYdth5twa8O//sbZJAdZyVCazOKk3tRxvNjH8X598GDLfYRlJ6eMz@JqfG0m8HJdSzoTjwuG5BrxY1LX4B0k4B9CdBbSZuUaV0pLiUSjGnlCIaxo6MjgRp5fFGW4sD9RlrHd1wIGI/HEUihaQktkRBPjZ7koQmHRqHiqW0izWkykhlGpgTjmxJDLxYejugwbkXPd@/eQWWRUUbxEEaUTNhnGJk8BYIH303Z6039nQRGpiDx4TTTc/wy6xjddacwRWIxtqVI3HyXIxEs90aNfD6KLgXqRItt@eY6OV3y5whpijBIwcd4@aziB@4dsb2jJ0/2n54OajUmWXQJoVUfDN2m5XnrBHMM0@0@fcSt@41CDtGIVKuY82nRQLEk7RdTJDQPHx0fnhQZp4mooVgASSnR/K8gRUGXIoPBi52IMGmQ8VYMVz7B3@Ks/DGjkMYMKyUp0rRwWAIMh/@sJD3xOg/dCYzlE7Kc0HM4RFNoBpVJX3eLxfI7PbMtwZPexwzPb@KbPaF1og24trNDRJMqVyrNeqMTKjgnVSrCNojpUuVk/xQSnB4x3UhpDEb6V5ltI5PNZI10LpfdNvRMrpDJZfNp6Gtyqaxh6IVMppAvbF9Llc/ZRENcVXD3yj3L6Yy6m2iRI5@l5BA9NqupBP4Z6TT8AsSEnt2ubWz0rlRE8IzY4gpNq67h9UpFCnwFPkz6isS@Al7wgTzQXooJY7XDo5KwGMJjFWLcbEjWs9C4FekMGImDkwbhT8l3QCuCMX/oK0U2vvGNEatUYKytHh5IERBWXeYbz6h2S@tqxE6t8dCi0A5jLfszG69M0Vq2N@iZU2iiKU2KXF9ftwHS4QGurNIrT9HC3@sm@TTAfT0xpf//8w/52RlUgE13koPKDj97iOHWxrI8siZ41Bn3kyue1WtruA@gLFMKQ94RZ/lVJJGwgjsqXLNVxg1wtKsKGqty1Sq33CZdxVRqaQ23NdW80RREp2CAcrTRc5vnUT/QxhsucTdX2chtq6IRQAPgDzWfyCeyCaNWZTG5KMerNbqpS9F4Q1I3NoDrLLOlwrPtOiNPNQq16zCqmHcFc0pgCa8EFkXHdazrotkG@XzV5IZsRdnI5uVStTR7387Jpdr1g77Vsk00aj9LXd1Ik0vJ136UsxTGWhInB3EAK0JG2hHHHFXI9KoKwqK2D31AtbbjH4AEvbVkGKqRVtO6qqfx/xaHgf93j2/Av4G/kCptSKe4CfApEBaEosMe43nLI5edui5drfXQaq6Isdc1ycZsb@h63t8jzkPTOedBj2x@8k4Q9ImJZ@p7fXvUXRHj@aCP@wet4T8ahP1@AxBEluYRHsLPsOe6yyJss@fPVpTySXDWHRCDH3YH0Y8PP/7kNPQ83d/d@0TKsYdHTx8tPLIiUpY93j84DV63eaifNBuA@Pr@48eLr@IRwe4Tp0E3WHbbd@gSGqneg8HDPeHM5mbOFDpf8P1TthcYTfKNckXp1N9UZTJsfQ2LNfmWThzN0HELQqnRtwuSNGCOe8m2U6zl9nomXivY3gDPrombRSzspnt0@yVmfekOe61Lu2VtSE9wX0pBx7vTEAnpEwDSHzdpb7M9kvDwnhZe@IfT7g28s3yMl2qu8IQHeqFzaHe6IAkvXT@C1DBNBt8P/UB6K/wZrfcY8TzI70ZI72Z0KSKhNmaOzEi@dO@e/mwInF3Jp4rFUbtjgcY@8Cr7E2AvNmbPgeHNIYq@zSTbzMq5pnzAtHrE3AIVqGNXvdrgmOVxMrhppjNboJDq2JuDFmZa2xGUlqCDoI5YNUAPQdHWyrigMchD2Sm9YU2JlYp//Vs/Ri7eSoLAiuiyjAazG7qkkYJnFPLZfCFtgAwv5DNZPZfNJnQjAfrzdgElvJ7Xc/lsQU/kM4V0BjQmCM0WtqUIt0ZKbhFIeBYBrNPEC792SEfUuhUpwldi2JuYqbCIGbyPmWxBGhmvePZGtCNvyy7LRobpKQbDA4BosiaLHBzspQ4OZPkhvuD6815Kllv4ks2nUtsPZdmikL08dn6yy9Pk8dwEecRfUqmHe7I85gDwyEFZ7uLLfg5nF2TZxpe93YMDzKeNLwamh2jnPIS/9PyXbYjm4Es6TdMTsvw6AAfxdnlGGcJ0H18wTww54CF7ECbLH/v4pFIA4ZjH4xA@8cu6uyvLh/xldxdD9qjgWY7qp/iySx9ZBu7AFiLLHXB0htA2ZbkBTmwnstwEV3Nqgh9er4bn0jkjU5annEBIIlmeUGyzeS7DEFz4YzaffPKJ2R21rA7/TIf82QTUIMSejPcPGh9/3Oh0GsPp7v7Hxxiyt/eJ2Z6Oh41OQyRr1OHjQhoIOe9PFz@A42G9bvaWhnwKIc5CSH1atxC3uvkacBKfDmbSr@9ByB6ELFvE4tDg04eoDfw87MPzodmgEP9DIfScNBpyCRkV9S@6IxXaDF1XmuibzaFbwvdJeYOxaCyamFZzqVqJAlgftKxU6ZouR43RnfQ4nFWuptVJOVUrT8rbBrd@aMfks4mRteXERv@@XsgWN8z7upGJT4q4L9dtR1lU1e@zmH5v6w2LPVXuG@lMUT67f1@Vq3rtvqHni7ntL7bGsqwU8fd@ersIEVNRGOzhj1Ldrt3fzoaSbG/HzaRR3N5WStdAjhH0ow0UIfVY7NIyzxUF0cVBCRSBX806pXLapXZskpiUOV5sqpQmZb3Ej0xiqRuwWng@37g5coccYgfATe6ninT5q6wX8jLkn0zGFAUkEwkReM5sm1587fT89PRzkFkw3BODpWf8RsGSeP34kz0Nxk/iDc/V0w5QzXWH2h4KlrkQfuyb73UKklP7BDpD0IN9P9wrMXR72v4EhrCoK/sB/mlJmjjjRjv9ZA7OCYwUec641bREByU4TYvhsYN2i5nlCrjMFgzSSdyZyiV1w/VKpVwv9/n9rZUg1aeMzuSbgTn0OO7BBlhKfoX7B0RAvZy6LjXKk8gE4NTLTNVf9t3WSyPeLLXwtMGH5YeYuFSHZ6NklS28xVaOyKX2fQfG3WPHM9vWM2uI27kPjzahr8FNBbE2s5RNdkZ33u6hznytVobMmWH2dNyPmWqlocx7hV6RNLGv@UW@ol0uuCx8XWqXWewLpfQaXoebLNbSHir3M6VW7CGrK@CTetl@2WYGy2VKdA1YDCFBIyLa0F2ySrnyKegxHPB5sQiIiDo@B5iYE4C1WxRgKgP7utQs91hMZROmEHkypU65iqnf4s@OKss1Va2@rUkVVX0hVaCdlqYRs@yNG3RELUs1dCOVK03AT9/OlLpQseYXk9KwPICxdKkHr2LmgG/mMUtATqAagHnzNvb@F7@p7KjZMvcrEai3PVAd6lq9PCk5eOgFsEQ5XYaAeDWTSmTzMLbKbiegQzagk88l0olMQt1GX50GXOCpQ6cf68VkxuREapLS9IRu6Qlo/S/t1kumJM5joHUQyeBl5O7jFbrgA5WEXEmv8DSZEje2ejAybLnM3FGJTUFSlLBgQPMuG9iJLoI6tswepVAUlaW3Yr3NGMbZPB0P9qu1YnF/MvgaBMXU1/dz8e1U/I2ilGIbStmzXkuVklRBqUKlHmwAz4pJFeaN@1Wo49Gmvm0Uq9UGlnA7lUin0lA8u/62syNX5FoitZHToYauGekxjAsMrsvMtJGZXx11Z7yPmukFoyRpZD9AOeoxo7BqF4gioeWaACgNhLBDCrPYmexvZ4tFo9tGNKpESzj9uiGLWTOQcPxqaxC10Xv6fRn0JxgRFwyMMBOUtGMpFVahriUc87JMQYpcSddX1zswuEySIRnogmyDXKpWeSBFioyBHncmzsRIbjD2ofZp8Z3KF/x5hhasAFeiQ6uqrEZWI5aNIyL2Ge7OvM@igJg57FcNI12rGtvQv4HM9KMahl7CyeUImspqFaC8dwX47cQruLHhUzadmnHVp@w9xjrxTYkKHVkk@255t3O8W/Lf9nBi60ySZbkUlSNX0Uj0Gv6kyAPaTWHw3RQsEtpPwS0wmxbQ512EJAbbu/InPYp4dULMLHL5UK0p757avat8WuWjexBY19eRzSTViDBKL3360shCHTmub6UOoxzUt6HrymZxci6SfDnwvmHk008Oj5xHwwOLcSP1fKYuVyIspato810qCt8sN1KVC3lDNs4TEfYgUoqwczWqF8mQnQ1OCl9sf5H/4snzo@dHB1LkbOPthosTt8wnC3vnfPVrEDGazkQZOytHJuVMSRgKVSqqvmPg@TPbDO8nb@s5NfW2wtm3QgE5A0Le/@JvZCY7eXg3QHstQhVm40alom8ZTIkM3n/5@3jMwNX@Z7uPWdQzp@zv/uRHxvbf/cm/JvOb6HXJo@nB7QjERKee245cXQ2urq7hw8OykVqEI5XZVsDNZ6T1yMxWvpg0za3teMZ44JSSIq6@rSsRT42IefftbMR7K4KMVB6C/Ilx8pJzWAWR/WM7a@gPdpAp9GCLDZutv1peAbgi/@TlW8bgpVlpdTq2Qa5kkhXfqWznnbrD3uHE8jt1g70sV3AxVMeNOf4c6lalUkEoLFqJJ7eizMhCWPW6VIszmoOFId8X1pazdTbP0WcbrFBwwN/ytsTU/dmWB8O6LYf@rC3Pg1f/zdp65TEZFxeSyVaLzl/ZsVi2AvW/lQR0zpT3v/jrhpH7uz/5lbf1t/XPDRi5FQo53Yj8TP/ZzyDCmh3h/rCLJppx6zY6guEaW3GXrtaEkSJesNxmPL4/eMPhGuoMdseBUTm@SReo51DV1PkxQ60YRdvCDaMJ0prpEBClJEmBdkla8bDTTBAMtoXnnEPblK6kr2AQdKasDOJS@soMFHj0oft0m3WvNx4OyAA9Run0WoLdgySQw1fwTKcN2ugqZK4KYiq5dTMpR9kjqpFOxPqW5@EJUdCLSF@BJOJMKry@1cQ92RjTdkDIaxiF8KSAVhXyrkHePZ6gTr4xKj2PkGAcO57IAc1Z@gooA0QFG3QEZu9AhBIIlq8AAaAMMQHYrrEdllbYlR2Pl2bHT12jMS@ey2X6@0ElTIbQWrj/2E9cwnjgBRo73oKCfCFqGNSzkKcPhMPgi41l0PkxOb2h0kUbtu8MCmDR4SgxKhq7d2@GVblstxRGJUL45/YA556oHpzluAIwf7z0UasoJxge7FXyfQO2A4rHCV3gOpWf6FUKJWUyvl5LEvzfmWmRIxeqigJKWABRX7xVNIFkkBjJzuuwyXbKTDe2FRYg3wTcm4QUHR0VDALPJh9pxud@4DVg@LOIf8YwSJ/T8Hye4NvFDcEMur0xHvCKx8JwYSA28vKDX1CKHY781EEqKIrdo9htewgDFFrs9E@RiqV1BZPNTt0iPMg818gwtJPNKvigVBibwdPE85JEPht05kPThQr1Bq5DByzRYRBoggwcATJKnFPD0R47l3gguKgbShzGyKMzapDzEWM6MIpuUqO0uHrYGMIo1qdNglkdjTX7LWYUWIwYjc7TcQJwCiUihBug7SKNGz2rDyidWBbDM4a8YjLZAa1o3KBDhZ7YwFfdAxu6EsdLikvrkpf2uZ08xQNNVbcNKrTYoh1BRQqbH1@oFAf49Fz3nPXsc4tP08bmNrh7DPR9UFoTQNnZFwhbxBlhI51gKQhO8Fjw3YbHNnfmE6G0G7GpcvOZ1jdidazRt9Qn2UO8kO7CdEL0pc9bSQxxvannH5FBBz3AuxaIXEtsji9HcV9ucOqDJA77KNM5ExpO1Q9iMOD0D8lAJ@ji1gXDwaqEfQwIzaa/3RxbMZT2K9QBUNuDloXnZY2GRTwkATAZtmJNaHpCwDvsI5Y2JIzITzARp40ADKz68jx0CIOkWA5v1IKK0fjWJpAr0Dr7LQjD7bmC/TC9z93oprPMZuzNNgQ47HQorzLjzcJ/yYZesHUgP1PRNyAwBxguwWQjJscBbFxWZA46SL@YnHO7RLKkyG5CSjCEIEgNUEhV8G@sZKGTuyUIeGh6/HhHcbLW5eWlRke8jYe2Znl4mrWH13AmBx0bdGI3ObL6A3FvkI33xQm4M5fKD7HHy1nvT@ha1MK9KX9KUtsrC7OCWLTtRbFzvMDDmjt9OhoGz2TxiKEObDrovRkTlhCc/4xa4srnvyLyn5qPXiMQxhDMJDFNNBMALNFonifal62SCLigBgnAoRYt3xOPVRz6L33Pd9mDdhDDHZHBv//e6J033Z6LOonMp05nWfMS@jGn/qt4H9gTSORYl2x3ODSnMQpXMDYycGxKag@bQrdPIeCEboZd8TP@7El1WptLPgmSQ6cWrPMO8dwX6Wo9UH7gI4ZPePgEwic8fDLL1M@2OqlxlQy9rrE4yPV4XJgfE8FM/TjX/HDEWQhBBsWa6RwExpzO@V3Dt1mm1D69@RvUY9lnDOCJARDciiWrX5xVz2qOZ11u1eLJDjC7TISAGgfQ1RrR9LIVuJH6vYvewPXmvBw8JQ56JYE3ejW7ghs4r2AZgwoixuD0svFgr05fLHVzhUAUGCCgHgaBqBrsjmK2UgqOHKVAYJyqPKMxR6wqkKmR9iWChB@oS5z0nLBhQLUQIPQPigRoQgjzWw6/u8CXDi@GeEWzH1el49b7eMBMtBYFSi40FS5rSlRJIaxU1UcTyI7qanmxKH44VEV1IShUzGtR/2H0Nz4Y/Ta0i@XYE8PyDqMkhZsK2lmBCiGaC1GVVcqhegUMkltmzxpCz7XP9VPRW0M2W0l/mMHzwSJ4l3ghYyxU@U2F1w9twZIduRiwwrRchiJOy7xZ8nbhk5QTPEjmiWRTnxFEei5AAEZqaTJLJJuEk03KZS442GRFsssQkhNCcsKT8NiTFUjWRDIYPQU3@WL11EA7RasuGeDpvBsFNWggM7yVEVekX@HhV7hKKfKcyRziAsFDqGIjnzVrS3OvhpAOCa0FAMiINwC0@DVIRWlR4Olq8BbIKE5KX0bxN8EGXFYAg5EILvEDImMBk9EYGBR@OU79ALRdOV6VZJ3mdfEvxb9ywvf0v/pNz9R8TH3e0zfUCf7@UTxrSNlQAw1pH3oqgwIZRzLPxf3VczpHBG8M7Lqg1TUuXRZbomyDf9K/@jrZ6LmNZN9EKxC8HCW4EFvxxw@4JsIeDNyROXIzmSIfNNnEdsvy52MGu@O4MDQJHwwLul7LtTwnOoJKbbodx/asBF7BzVV2i2wS@DHYUlhPFk7XkyQxB8mHsQia8xWquvU6XtdWr8fQgEspBgahZM@F7BmNSjj@BVcoPYgnAfRoEHMbr6zmSLkdJp5hLJKd2s3z2NFABEYhk10GMqwJ@j@EdkGDYZ47GznSaaqoSjdGMTpsvev23Q5ofWNPkzD1AvjDGWxEyBwMCJcEM3FIWwydZE2tJNZMmIpI@ukHJ2WfGjFTCdIb8wDmiJFgw0UaI2WHS7Krr8yOJ/PzO/lwfE/C@J6sx5dG4Ys486F5mQd@WNbp2AwCRJyhkb4dDSw6yK3WDXTmUAm8Ua/iCe6MYousrFqI6S5E3RXRtTbwRyJ48@AtQPyzVfRfX4F@8v27Vp@Jd1ieTEHe9NH4L0bH4Hv@4mYMoh8qihRZkl3A2o/umBfExRtIDlCFADWWBJeDB0FCwxzAsNsLjif3Ad/C82gsdYPvyYKqzAOX4DS8SLBzY3UVPaq3rJ45tVoxETMRguuX@BgGbCSv7lZwFHQk9Fw@1otB36UEodCNI9F5pOIKljETF4qymq14FDvgHpopJwwPV9MPw2@IZpziK/PZahgHRKN4KJlzYeP052A6mPKzhnv89gIhR3n/w2sSN5rfThCggzhqJTHLVlknPo9jQZHu0CMEcbX5IuNRoD5EPGXzZh1@GIluLylUbihR2a9laf7c/OU1bq@r8RBX@DzJ143uxpK3Md2deS7EahzYTITtfVgXcgMy2mM0m7EwRO6ztsZc54ZMQD@ap3NW9Cr1JQI1SEmSbmTTcJv0C0XCkfEhPHHC6TN4IsCONapzhvLLhnNa4loRRiF9cxDSWoQPKOkAJURFTnKBRiiW5Lsh@tV1kGdzZZ7NG3k25/IMWsB8lqFIUnMuS1ELWD3rqqBntUcrpDMG4dgZHuvENnwc1xzibMVV1I4W7QSLXkSLIJCjVrS4HwOhHG1Fi4/I4UWLJ@Q4jxY/BcesbUXfRot@s8AIQ3glxwP0FyIc35vR4l5MuZZG5rnl@flq0WJQpxDnPn8ligApsNygNeISm@OKYo6GFnRspFQmGHKMl8DhE83DJOibgn9@EwadqI@BOMe5RZFZnOlznUaox@D5QLfhn9i8pCUXRW@@f3RA9kxBFMwmDmO8cBoCD2p4JDovjDhiGEorGvAEBFFuFpdjxEI92R3REbkDh1Ilz@dP1NNIH2jFKLwKkWuzTOj6E5Her695ELwC74YnJl6F5w10/OwII1yTVZaghUR9GV1TKKzreVxE7YdriOa65yPhJbB@FF5LBDYk00GHo8U5zGzgDuaZhELR/t0Op6FJOd4okXsXkpFUEC1zRTB5i5KhYAg3fmVdcULpELU5EYSB1VSNt7KgXyBZjEEzWRfSVHnjAxRCMgdauNU8p6tlHgknxePiJkF9xapuyE/LsyTJNS8mIbGGJ@aMzRHPPRi87uM5Oh82fPVTTnCuJYYAQimDXLh8dT9Af3e5/u4r1D4RFjJYplgv70pvqtdre9kFzHuzbG9WIAYm2CNlqXIU5DAjOYwOQpr5Ol67oeKjyQdX8nmmAfQFbd8nWzAmuIVui2MLDgu1hOHFvOe5AZ7nxmpC3dRIehear7RomJOAwwseYDor2npcecGXVTGG0Py22fvgCh7OV3C48hAeFWC4QHLeyodjh6xcZm0bxDb3QZGqFxkX5LRcGlTzzBPEPS3dBsu24HFUP3509PTx16HT3d7eVkQfPZ3hh60W51qDfpxDJuPooD9YMmwxEnhbBC5243Q8Xbi8cebIN2QJF9agDJiQi89@oo0rQpaF5PlC24V0PG6IogLW@awZmHNSCVUdE7tsW9B1BASxRrEtUwDx1Vugd4JGawrdi1Cv4yW79Tp1X/U6Gi/V66IXw6rxV8SVn0U2kmNvSJf88Us9LiWJtrqzR0fsxSe7p@z0k3128HzvU/b1o@fsxe7TU9yy/Oz5w8eHewy@@09P9pk0Zx6JFyDhgBLo@shqWnhzHR43lmEEec8dTLncie0p3P/E7LNP3KaFy1Q7ntl/0OUvmmONKjzVPgxHpziHadMlV317hPYWdEMTDGNRuWnR/jq05WcQtwFj2j6Oeftuy27bEFfCse/Atjx/mxfr2VCDIG/9naUJriThZUxkOkTXpqEF1iUkNyE@rt0AGJPbX9E9xrbHE1gtjQnCBZ8PpuDp/vGTE4ab4veOnj46PD08enrCDo6O4fXZ1w@ffgz0PDw5PT58@ByDKOKTo0eHB4d7u@TBEUhpDLelvxp7o7UoaBidqNI8x5Vvuq46eJuf9UYNnl2atNPQY9Gxg9LHNnv2G6sVLUljD9UX3N1ISwUstrl7/PFn0Ocz6zWucPpLwWR/ID/36FKwzRTbodygsVSgvZVEc4VuT9UVWo/oTxneEWCVaAd6jNwJ5gMnI56WbTF5D21UcO6bb1SntuyDhow2ADaC8g1Wyozu9ohGEzsEsgK5NXsuHjXIc@NGhOIFkz7wTU1KElFM2MogUNyvcOjgfJBeCjyA78HDENmOhjwCSwcePALLcA9URQ/RdoRlRYzx6GiM4pnluMer/uCAloXZduDx0KRRbF7gxOuNqtRkwd1IuG2/Rze48FkeulnO9Jq2TUk8io@3m/R6vGFY/F4tkIl8KZFs2yCmDMKmjUsNwuyNX0mJocANaCdktkcei5UVjZ2icZDl2PzunE7PdLgJ1Mx0h3iP5fFglrIws7WDO2doB8jAJQbE@67m8QjSPRJaoXXXdJDy4Y0cTWEjSfe@@SZotyHw8AYCPw8YAKTOjXSa1FPRhlIE47YFK8c8FzgS523fheMDO7fGTWsugbDair2y37xRBJETc@Mk306RsIMqemMNQa2kpcy2O4Q2TmKVbulAKdjsuoORzeswNl8CWnGibg5iY8cGub0sV@ZyQzos5ui4TijTBnDxilwbwJR3yZU4nq@dB@JrdmUjcD50wtzuDtExG3hd82ztLIGLSJcWTr@AIkxr5Tj5OR0RJlz/lGay4x3DW9/y5cqjh2fqu5cJvPqNiwV@26JvdIhfYEzMC5oHrfORweIQ9S7R0vwre7xxA1MLGzwhLbGV@8BgHNi1YVz3oF4Kwri58U1/3COz6E@eb9@WeSoVJZO4gNPrxmbSLcGqfpYJSlNjwgQkJDsBWZD1Md8nQTADef0A98VgLZSAIg7KERy3L1yII0SIX7rGuA2SRdxLKKo7gK@wCllUzK5pxZ0t4fpIfhF7WI5XlOTMoISFyBnzRXTCh6wrSsgshfqrG@AerQcH8vvu4PJrsePdwwdBe7QW2gfhpsZXw@LdUgjW3cG@WwOWd24/F1goe2I1YN5J3oQWcHrAnInNSGBNuz7HlzfqjtoegMG@F2dQAqCh3MYOLVH7B/vGeAIlDGamEJ2cPto/PmYyH59AWpB7OGRoCTGIsDfYs5m1re2QsNMCpSkYLAfKk@8zZ9Hmf9Y15qXEWyEqhA6SEPQIhMXsQuK2PeFST/QspEKQ9T0JRJ9y89hd@TLIqwrA1zAGBGRnlRYqoLS0mBHe@dhe2Ahc0C3BdeOwDT9ZWPO@G2/7G07DgMI2QWYHd5Ysr78XXD8u@vlwBct6PaYCt0CThv4GxgknkPEAImrafA2uqRa/StHInivYEZ92aPiVmtew//4MRYzElXCuC4fEulCOBWpcP9701RwySMRuwERLTxHILZohwBfx5LMTrlBl1unF5rsgUDLx/rcHYa6A5LXrUnAjeWzWT5YDhTzc1jYJm6qPZQ1nZwXs0upIH6EtdG5RPCxmBdJ2bVbqP0xWvJeYy8mn@dLC@IEAOZfNpm@DvVgKP7n694XN@5BF@TnqD2B8PwPpTT2a3gfOPXya8MNnDLCGdNy03m8wCwlB1VnSp8yVnTqjMH6AC58XAmTwQG28Um8xV4VNFnBbDp33SGHoFOVGGUJNOCgobzU3qH@9PjsUyLfmt/Hh@fHGhpHQdPAarfKfuEPPmu3KC52iEvLC/avzftZw6FA0vp@pj1BitI1p7WY72m3HDV55qTCQ1tvCJWmL3Unc7DbhzzVQJjS9qOEtmji7V1qc3lP1UrioB4eP99kWHXTXnpuLlIeyEpI9G7azDgGSwTQv8f8Ud3VbbSRJ@pp6inQJGxVIJQkbjBHCLUDY6sHgQWC3j8DqQioJTQtJrRIgtWHP7F7sC@ze7yPsq8w7zNU@xWx8EZn1I4TtPn3RPseoqjIzMjIy8i/@EssH@/A9DTbpP@GQMSCJTOzNl2baON/EjSlCu@Y6X3KizUL13FqY7f120PT6COmRsZ8Gys48o4Isha0c7TvzJOv5YqI8IRcM@2kqlbGzrs1F6RsEuoCUBCG9ie@xBQueGsZS8it3n3u5wkZ@/ZXFretnxpmr@qvzzHKzZCtafL3@VXA9um390hlc3rRVTw3/djFpTn/7Vam1F@o51bX6TIKcFtZLOY4Q@ZL@bqhXeeZcjeBrDth6Zivlyn1rSi2p6BxefKLkrjE@NG/CQ2KGS9XyleFCuNiNS1f19fNSv5QvXtX750U4@Y1XSuOVwkoaH57RKkpzjGjm6@NzrKlxqavfv1G4hpOvS9OuIYpdQ@jLO2/UHRyUD98kpHHYAEAEpm29WaAuN2guwJoNvidu379NazFZRoFjLWyQrAX2CirAp53lyRDHtLqEGfVKhnazwYT/Th1rIe9eD8cDTjFx8cBa6q57Zy0YN6Y8SxQoS717btDZYjhRnjQUQ/J1KlbU2YJs1wrwnXRiIOooydOhfWbb8CkEotqXq35uBa7vNS@BBK6MveNiamuLL5AlVgtcluLBlMMbscNE/hyPUIDQz5C1DaiCd@4Bu31Y1Hy8F/AgX1hGNWY/GTaQt3iniBSYf6sv7N/E5beIAEL4BdlzuVrEqXdetJEU30EWLiDqWPLgDzUD3CqlUxbQWMCW@koRcLYUZxqhWk0m@r5wC3IKreifbkG2wG8PmhHmdyQ7k4T11PotAC25SzlpGz@9qFg6VixripnMMVIsfJMakHTR8eidT8Nqqnb9Xo@QFlosROTAI/v36vpXwvqDOuo8D5GX9OyD9Gwi3ZV0QSrK5dICH2XajGeyU1@ifPfKjrJlHtRVUrx5camnmy5tSaK8xa/lDdzxoNGNMm@HXSlcGSZsJRKysZTPc3pfUp4kyoQMHqbXJV3z96ru@RDLRN4fkvXj19Id5LPxrLY1meFSt9/tvZZFK0wBm9lETaWkOPqb2U4GpfbB1NMJ7eAg5@dhu12KoKwUzIzDY8be3vrBdvUm43V6Fg3xYnwwsOaMkRiVuM4VJtyEHRapHk5@EgPBMMFoyozcbVN4qgtPY2CR64mpVrwgHwxwatrsEC/BL/IOf8xgTyJn8qXmJy4I5hNpvHg3JwnEk@4Tez6ZkrMJ3EXko27UV1aRqO7pLMT5k8RhTAoc1umLD3YbYvAn4TwRnyjMTPGA7mGKpnSUoWDY97EuROK99a/csvXGoz32sOdPVBnHDI@9sKyEg/vYD8YBYjtxLJrgejjsQevIG75bdqHWgUJW16BuiSDGVnbXqsKyR/Jn8KQd0qmQq44A@RYGIlFCcN3pwJkMHrCDW0ytkLh0x65V7k9FoEFj5vmquJn76joQrSmd9jtxJKTnZPSA0sHQa/quRXu0gHY/ljS1LeNby9PhN4LoYbSkbVrWX6@7zV9230Cf@7KQf16IkexGq4Pz7vMXkYMVEckkrOZpG7tWeGFZMd1wU3TDWQDMqAMs9B@IN/0bv9/3rTKtGJwxoE1r4I9u/JZrWcd@qAQGXLAyNJPwwx5cj5oi3KFNl0fMCC/hICPqMOIw/GJ9FnVxk3VlGQtKq0jbTF19022BgMbjpD2AdpgVFggTIPRAoSt/TERZdlQSJdY9a1x473IFQRRRA3FOYrqJkAz9wbjbpJ5hSZbVI1CiBokq67dmMKH6mj0PzsHuPATgHhNRwCBgVElfw8HSSvPfhYPSDTM6ds/0TI5mvwGPFRru/qhLs29EYO4VLhbDnTr45G21pmpH@ycfy8cVRc/vj48@VPcqe2rnE@u4oSjn8LXq7dEBzS6hNl205kf0wS7XqKTNCVb58JOq/PT@uFKrqaNjVX33/qBK0Aj8cfnwpFqpZVT1cPfgdI@17wRBHR6dqIPqu@oJZTs5ynCtppgVlVNH@@pd5Xj3Lb2Wd6oH1ZNPXON@9eQQlUGrX1bvy8cn1d3Tg/Kxen96/P6oVlFomLVXre0elKvvKnsu1U91qsqHyuGJqr0tHxzMNPTo42HlWLGRQKyVOxXCsrxDR1jUxO3cqx5Xdk/QoOhpl4hHCB5kVO19ZbeKh8pPFWpO@fhTRgOtVf56SpkoUe2V35XfUOOs9DeoQv2ye3pcQfwjUKJ2ulM7qZ6cnlTUm6OjPaZ1rXL8obpbqRWVdXBUY4Kd1ioZhYvYuGqCQdSidHreOa1VmW7VwxNaM07fw97BoU7@SIQhLMtUdI8JDDMItJaIdHT8CVBBB@6AjPr4tkLfj0FTplYZVIBFxe5JPBtVSEQ8iTdTHVbeHFTfVA53K0g@ApiP1VrFoQ6r1pChCoOMT8Q6VOkptxr9RHjJIzGrZTg3w92pqvuqvPehCsx1buKAWlVzC5Nt962muYtouDEhSncAmYF3FRestB9@uvERXPKhRGa@jCaMmLR7tFehFVkHq7KjhFNadTZmQinF02ilCRPpNRGypuVfXHca3X57AB/TsJgIPq6CTgY3mji42OHM@srFEVq@wgVSqUbjQ7lBB91ao@FkvqdkAo1vldBi8K/lcnQbEbMeJ28IfjY3he5bCUJtP9OKTjbUgwICOYX6z8T0zbvyHZXLtXxdDM77AGxER4GoTS6hSqGpkZ0dcftEVCVLJvi9q9mBC6YNeLfZgJwUlpGcaRDQn/5d9CKLQ@wDzc4i7srlcIhlNLq/@aYaqYRDIvAfHZGg2@Yq3cD3f@mk8/HqcOZ3O4NBK@04pgznHdM5sJN2vlH8wu/MFM/OlmdkWe2sg@UH5tzNW5hQ/6xJpnS/uCNuWRp/GmP@cQw2EvMBUlOuioXVWmiZfibFYZGUUTq0BdwruJOx53tX/qn6Eae5/OqL4sz3t@F3GVuwF0QQWlrw6lzunH/enksGGmAci4NI0tURMnK5WBljbxJmvqWMl8h0223B8ofW6kuf13UiCW1kr71evE6sxqPuJI49zcNvjsvvdk7392nqBLYvNtZerhetMOzWTxn5/YR6OFIsRx0b0jpO@zROio2SXdr48EiJxdKO2J8ZOJdDRoRSN53GHxHnIbTbSFoyYSJDcwNcxdKHiZ7tgw624gAcTyzDr3NHpmaAdKKpDlpz5U14i@/RXol5QBuz9KbcaxP8Aexw@JshHjZIM5BmMY6dS5xLpwue9@x9YyrKhxsO3IMsrm34WMK4hTRgURfbz8K7lt80b8d6MRBTRoxX7nYuSUg8mcVCGbuKvozs9xxnRAuAOXoYfflJ8xs9ftIB7jjcnReMy@MakXE/LAk5dSSM1o2ua8jn2yXqomfPwpq2FKT8jkaKx54WJ4eBQWKjgVE5h1FhSc0ALoZxRGarZAvYH5Yc9UU4FcE7AKeoOVa/E@fOa46GUjTxQ/S7iUqhBFYY5ESodhvWYZksn8I4FoacCTL9IXow/D@RJnPgb9GJk6BH1IoFAfwuSjJUoRUdX5ko3VujaIhpNyJqxj99isDcxzvmMmyY1t5MxL@GSKB7Z2o@fOKwh@30HAKAySHYiI/f0CTt0qOj0w@2o4tDT9JvXg3TSq8VZql4ADe7fp7hbVfG6Fbw4ihHZE2xCg@oqPpBDm4XPOrpyDRzlFdPA1vAOSb@R26ZBSDhgGcuvRSr1VnOyutRZuYBHWoptuC0wohJtC29f1Rrt6xiITITc7/WfBlCEeht4POwnXzHx0CJeW4y4iKvxOqEo@AhHjiOyVh8dMi6CzbE7PmA87TFwhBcAzK@xQLRE@gcqi@CptJP2VAElURWh1GcQUy3jkuk5WX1NsSeJZPg0BD7074EovdFqmVyuBLgQ2MYd5d31TtvSij3vq/ZwmK55dogA9tFVCZiCV0eV540B4MRbR09tJtwzHSnjqs@aqGD3w@uRzp@Ia1n3ZGWSJhNP1WDbZOc3nmZkRjwjFrQHcNboeUyf3CTrnxYiEp4kkl2XaWJeQ2PbhuhY3eyUlDprShli2jCYUmZiFtqXd3dSS4hqA4Z6jMFu0F4uGCbTa4Heodw@N0ORr9g7ccWqN/yW2Fk0hhIlgVKJ1X7HOOxOZamDwcBSzSoKyABCSlREEFaaKhKa/RLzU7arsmOomMidim35PfXEzKpsZaiiiLG1bUT861nqTNBpVUdGjQMFlpYXWNU5h247h89jHG00KTaWtln/XBK2ZRNROmp2TriSebN8OkTnrSQv/Q0wOihL9Bx6y0oEMaeFXrVh/Mc4webgo9df9SKy0RpJ9PyhhC/8dFn0GdeNKJDHfav6Y0Df0ongGauO8kxjEb6x8Flv7E76Hmd7qDr0TkNYdwnMuPhccqP6LDOaHAb8G0@nNCKZWpNo2eJLyNh2PAe6iWLsdBcwdgfpuNmCuPRtHwpYSJYcg4jwOhKRebv4WyMtLDMi7WokJX0P2V7vIJTfLTs88K8wqLRBwA9wW3PWFCID@mYHZNizqfFBxkuvpYhhuOFyirPecRiL4HxKyIRq2ESGBtkHpglxBuBk9mjGNdbk0yLYxCOEGjJ3/Nx5UyQ5s8ZD5fX0izyGpYCm6qwkY8VFS3KBHEI8TB9nNyrL/9k7AmBP4B@4fk8bpnHCDzFtU20pUDOKzrKKOHC5oFdnqN5JqZZrNuhVaiXANqYzEJNJk8fowZb/tCmSIfZe8CVGJFpOvjggrh0g6acxtTBorKklhyO24EtSHmczj/OsP637Gd58EOJK5IzTEy7GnI6hvRjpGoSlXBP54x5bRxlian87RGzuvq9vTZDwNI8k7PYfbRp2@xc2AOlK@sr1FqDEU3G9gz1tKnHUjAeDJe@k3qPzh1zI7PNo3XTcb5pCCzMVqLFcrnFpC1N8TgtWrP4zDBNkmJsaUY8hOMrP4dsPkvESamB8VZqTL9Bh8doFtlNhYtK2N8tGftYFG9g0WsWmnBIMe4IUloMv9cb1PDG4zOIhinHqwbPGA1MGY2pPMZAzZAppNL3U4i5T@M@Q48WUQ71toh28f55lKizRnIm5KlJSgS5BD0RuB1OmzQvDdswvkCYONnhhpNUuOGcZKasyitkLxBkGAkCELtiPxvJoUSCG3XWDB/x7QDtdAPWQgXMRPS0HbdwCIP@hwTjqPxauKMtHhrTbOG8KJAmISQ6VXCur0Ey/ub0Wm9MGMoDUtAQn0OKsEUP5qbL72/VH20L5SMIUpqTtaVvPoPGOGqFsKE/8aTGBHvgqCpdMjGikgOhwVMDjQU6pXR6vhxXsfvrjoTjYd2ghxEdIORzGj8rugTCea/nQ2qjyKQ1RRZHk1tGm6Oy21IkYih5B/n1UJStLh9cCYAvGFP5UoEgIKwpYw@lAIfeiXNeAlHdR1SwVMCwpI8cFTWy85yTDqLqDC/WYjny83K8isPIzgVCG4v5eSJEaM8yP0sEhRa6ubjEcryc354oB22IDe8LxakrdK8kaRj2nBCQHhnbcEapF1QmrzmYE1@sOYnEkL859VU@lpqfTSX6hBjWs4XZ1I18IjVR7epqsmiiJNHDideaSCRSOHGEw1nhj/1j15R4yPPQJjR2yEjsMrR9dh9HqVuc29y/BWqLnbLNHsPAi3uGm@NXQ65YSQRl/3oAdrXEKgPEbv/DrTWWqQYTfVcAx6Uzzi5pORDyjtXGUo9m4aRrIu2FAQrMmXbQVh9O9vcTYV8vpsbQ6MofreXzeTDxRTz4vbGthiipO8glc@fa171ebnj74@jDRY7nftxX3wsGm@YE7VOX0KAI3MGoIzdDAAfKitxZ7ciKs/51ux2/ggEaSnQedZvk1NEQFC9A3dDo5cMJC4AYpF5gf0YD0b6fVTj6bj3ZaGooRg1FpWESfGMb7RmRBx/asM8ONVUMDBOzsWaidcspbX/BCoKbTbizOHyx8yUyT7bf@r3eIKM@4j5gRApYuJ8tsL8fL5CXLNAwsnfvdcDxaDPKv@n2Yn7FyBLndYAzC5O5Z8LEhUds/GO/U5kM03b9s03LCjV5Bc1cQXzqjLI7tqODxX8HWOFDQvu7cl95w3ST6TSbmZZ6PYKjJ8LoeSEz9@yTyOKwTEzT7Nu5QdT56LocrIGa7vBewMSy5@7lljySPSSufTYptEHDvMDQOCHmyveVgKvZnzct3ozb7e@bFfkaAOnY3zUjyk0of2xCZB0Aj0A9/IieiKL9lywN6/2ZgCKywcFlHQ/nHRRooIBlPW2Wfr1Nl8tltThcWVHl8g49ZLOqvFNWe/iws6P26H0H789Kq2trRZlz95wv9HHHfLxXOwSDJZwrzcvRHr1SWgl@Y7DWRhcv5kqLmeJio7S1XQxy9fIO3Prp6Z///p///I//ypX1y//gZYdf6p/DTK7r5habXxaf3RfxXt87X1q8qC8Oz5c6RXDZvzhq@KA6znqR@ag7urBSsgrEvrIdqTlnc/QZXVSZW/2uvNEvNLtsqlQzyKX010BujuI5NtX0Y999@FFe0BHeXDowe5QnJFIEdApxPPVO04cBHq03REnCBXagUl50K0Zwj3AwYYZQq5LSkXh4z3rjw6cliqQAX1xasbLdfuD3IQG/4T2vNM@yPPrtjhuaf3Of3wWdncFELZ@l1XJeLWfUsm3zT2H9FX11FnNdeOdKNjoO2HaGUiLVAswMVdDljR6fH/iunRlyW9YiX9kDSCZMBWcWL7hMePpjZxm5cC3oWAu4NFOJiISVTCiS@rLYv6du@UI57u2Eqw1vFBr6FMOVxTQqYf9iC@QFYggQ1XwlBNkcUJXQ9LFHMp5y5ovua4tvE2LAIOvxm30e9/hAa9FiX9s8J85SuOaIzeflK9bGojhDM9pIkfojBFihIsfJPHsSLqWWLLHyjrWSmyle2PH2aeYTW4epPza26VLo31SMCcSaO064xb72a9GG3KJeUXY3VK/EqrJnbb@VFStydd0bd4faXYFrx4D6EtZ2LyMJPcqABI7E7N98OMJYUGAiRc10i1yWNVWtAZouI6GvXdOpgx1XNEcxIuQ@p2ls382MbSfHXiKGHYQHGKnQlK/tdXuBjroyYmJ3vNEFbgf02nyh2lj0ZizPwzWpMxgP2iHSLkNmk/NoPFNTUsOR17nyMip1ODgZedMqLVu08xk3XYdaiBBMQAKDT1c9r3kGYWmR7hKmSNgUthzC5QW9qb4eTfrWDn1O0KVmKOiwKxgECXZiSvp3ib6aoWPE1b@jE@IoP5i8Q22knmJ55oWlkYZkx91meJg9GDqWqSE@dsKBY1uCajgyDS/oQtdYaK9Y8UszeQ8xAnTdtvYC1K4I669QP1anjt/3EovTsGcZR/9cUcm6iPHMV1GKNZJlbj4tRDfeASvaR35ORoGQtcmEM7IW0umFs0Bf55aKryMc5Du0xc95qhteQMcXmLFniDrtd2WynFmhojswXFVly3@C0O55HcJveutNwYpnqfTrJzmn/vmsf76cPuvfnf3mMCZ6SjarbFaltDLbzFh6rNDKmMskXo1VWmBCDZ71kxnO@kp8WGIkIERy6frn3PldjhA6S@FO@bOUECTRZcAk9/X6cgCfe4BmKolFLmUtOMuO6fz064KjaG3lX/ShfHDkl7Awh0oW09M5Z9QmUOyn@@u1uJwEuY3V/IvVwgs6CXX8SXbkX2O9zQbXF/6EthIBjrO09Jz9luCGBCHuJ4FXpI8TaqdcayK@J4F2UtJTqB7mXI8VshWVcYUnKD9RmcOlwsXFCfN4UD7iwJ9RxHImL8eCEtPBGPelsX4GgyvU4wWY12a9Q4QjYWUgNiIsQs0Csrl85TEOdcxwWWI/J1ftInYrA6HuzaViq0V/0M/qzZrjLhWxiYbXTG8jv5GfHaMPhmhihC7qzdTSE1XYfv3yH/999GtqnNpezX0c0e849WtqfSMlj/RAb8/N201qO7WFbOv3qWmOzsD0@PIf/0vlt38kOEiZbtGf7TUDa32a2s6WuMhdanudHgqrq1Tv//3979SGRTmx4S7WxUZGMWJFQ5Fdr8@8S@mqilbKsXQpmlbYMQswxMKQzub0AsOoyepGnsV0KW1VcePryFfGHkUv8WyYNWZTIZFkGHsK2hlJgRIqyApIY0LRVjHbDWO2AeaN0FQ/P3XXAzoB/KzNOcIqQ9ONpwFMhhblWEQdmJYa6TwvD9v513Zo3rFpG5uSotlC4min59qN58X/Bw)
• [try only Haskell](https://tio.run/##dVVtU9s4EP6eX7GYzNQudsZOQuAi7M7x0oMpLa9315kcDYqtJBpkychyMQVm7uP9zvsj3NqEAyZuPtjZlZ7dfZ5dyROazx8fY2oggmlHzPPWKng3kPCcTgSDG6oll7O8NYR3aSEMF1wyiFWaMmnetVosnivwJFhBd3MIFgFdyNk8Bi/OskW8ly0b/tIW7@sXNqOGf2eH3DBNRb6M6jagTgqa85NCGdYA6DcAPtMZj/eR7KvtrzCbvzRgtqmcHVODdcmlLF1/vQnBJdW3P6PS9QcNmL3SMJmwZJdNKSp8WgjWgNxoQP6aZYLHtXq7qpFX12/i9aVId1nM06YSg8Yeqc9KqlTpbM7z9JTlRvPYcCWX4UGT9gg@VDEVKE/SkLKpwWd1imZSQf@ngF1q6OsEuBmV8zzPAliFl5/3dZ@VH4Wi5rlZr@J3mwo6@s407sdGVZnwSCzx6DXBTtkESVdn6exWGlo2M@o3Dcaxys2Ul0cZ1meUXk44aBL7d8ljlSxnW0B6DZBzlmaCGobH44oJsQxq1DtWGUvObzP2B9W8IpgvcbN6fq9Z/UNW4uSKp8Ov5ONjxNNMaQPHmokiYWRh/ra/0zk4eraq7nY@FjJGOTo7SubmzcpTY55d56w0nX2mWaLiZx9ijFais1fGLKsSPy8c4lEv6Ix1Fhp0zvffxDmbq5unzAjKCcfUVMYMqtHmCdAwwn80AbuuCqhzM8fMMI6icBymqK@5bUX/oz5BPXovYQ7yp9rhQBo2Yxpq@N1Uq3SxMA79BzIJy9US44xD8ILLVCWX3bWYJNXMb4fbFZiM8T0hLGRaK22tWmT6QYYAhczplB0zPVU6PThqA14b8RzsKTCnDX/tVbt3qBB3D16kQb5UhneFTb1o4rx1vTIraeyTZ8p3OZpYrWU9kGkI9jeHXKOp22AnnW3nQ58k9jaMHfT4l9PLKXRh0CexoHluV5GAurU2FWfqhNEnoAsxroZDLGTR4yuMWWXCsDypF6iT8QcSh8L2oHRqcfpkFo4q7H312PIs68LzRvcXrcjz/mxFZeiT21Ua5sXEaIqXjT8J8IomJfrwI0Lm2Fb6rSQ6zArNiEBTMDkz8zbUJClBMVEzDPPj3v73n7@dLW89fPKROtS9YAbGnXFYEllNOg5E2AtxYW3U9931TRcfG@76utsduMHA7bl919uovIG76a676AwuVlZsYeP5sVy/9DuBG7DABdu/5MklOO6V7Q@HtWBoGLUnixTQgy2qZrI28U3BWeu@F4A9UEC3vHpIR8EFqYih4nPIuDuvQp0yKmqE43jQe2@Ltl3taZ8X2d7oYjjcK7MTXLK96w@DtQ1/7YfjEHvFCXN23YpIK0oplzXrbAUnNsywWQblKtIRdti0q4/5aDSpGG74Lt4OSI@P72dbVmRduP7KIMAOPUDrPw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/fluz1)

`` -1`mod`2 `` works the same with NegativeLiterals and LexicalNegation, they are separated with `l(- x)`
(length of `"0"` or `"<function>"` respectively). `x` is used instead of `0` to fix ExtendedDefaultRules.

GHC 9.0.1 doesn't like `#1""` on line 582, changed to `#1 ""`.

Answer (score 3):

## 305. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE7), 14310 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;ppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




































































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){d=document;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=267-[0,0,0,0,10,0,0,-8,8,5,2][(":"+[].sort).length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-29]}</script>
<style>
*+body,text{display:none}*{+color:fff}
a,b{-color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
b{color:000;-top:-90}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[ s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1ute_[2]!!\0/ad4ocod"r"n;z c;op>s0}e}tf 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rk@PKdSD4WfD8iCywbpMoEiABvskiu6urq@8tqburVVV9@0osXjZIgiS6SIBNkFVkV1eHpNnVWmPvrEcjO2TZ4ytrxrPyeiLGO7GzlnfsmQj764RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzmZAEEWyeqW7IiNjQUJIJGPkydPnjx58t00vd7PfhbBiz11@7Nu3x2zseWNWXtkX1gjjd2fsXum7WWNtCShr71RdzKwnLFXkiJMZ8wbm6Mx65tOd2J2LRYBW4PNvzt2f2yNEsyzLNa0@u4luKcZc6xLdui07DZAYmP33HLs19YI3DKMPbD6bwZvxqzlDgam0/bYcGQ7Y3LNMvbUhI/OpHXOzKY3Hpmtse064JRj7JnTNwfNtsnI@3Bk8UB5BqBa5xRm0aXA2GN35FkQg9uyPM9FyyJYmiPbfbT35OMl/3qKfWwCUsO@NV2KXtfZc9satZdDGOzT04cPl23T7Cuq67CHN1HSM2xvMnYPx8vws2yvazkmM7SiZiw75oCYY6tfSBVSC07g9tAeQW6aItdK85xxJoOmNQLiiyy8tMc9DQKcupzgzHX6M2ZNARjg2AFv1pjZmFssm0qhT/ifWC3Xac/Bg5UFcACuNRiOZ0xljit4AJzcEfOGZstS21bfHthjq836NmDndgQ2HoMMZ@fW7NIdQcarnBUJEW9oteyOjUFECjwJme2B1Zx0mTsZDyeAnsfatmc2@@CtOWNtq2NO@uMEa4IbEI/sL3uWI1CynS6m4/ncBiE4UAQ49ts60Mbu9xmgc47oYNQe20WHS7RHr02LsLTaCOpgTi6AZPY9P/WLES9Eg@GejtzuyBwAo7YtosGnh0@Z13JH8AU3@uWlYBOYljlmu7ssevDkQZRVAzJqo6YUkLTCrhhjEd@RXZj9ieWxgTmDuJ0xFC7mUv75ISTwzqJb0RKLptPMSLFMhmWgsBWYkU0xKBJFMECpNdI63DlmFFhGB77PRhMYT2dkdu2@xaF03X4HAeWRY40sM@CZykQT3LVFceRZusByeZbPsjw8i6xoQCQIMcP0YhbuHNwAoQgY6HCnMzymgC2QnSAJbJ91zIHdn3HowyGCb7GszvIAEdDUAbJRAAhFAyEsXmF44x4QtmdeAEi1b5@juLACiYG5lYRXcmcnSSILZSOP0utZ/T7GCoQCEmULLA@x5iDRGYgZ6GgUDD/x3R4ln/DKp@AGHPOQ4gKQNwWUSiGp8nDDN4ghA@SNAcLFAHlh6GBvgDmNUMFfDtxykFe5gLRGm2gL0hXC6khMFCg60gCCMci6dIZB5mUge9OYvdk0AzwBgXyOgUwp6KyQYYU8A3IVUwxIrwMymPc6yDIdkNARGGSpDnmqAyI6MIsOQPV0lkkhuuppdIewaQgLJNAzECYDZsgXPYc3hIOM1yFKHeI0jOKctQA3IwuJzKaJ54wcZF4e3IBYBuBqALcYgK1RAHcMWwDCFZAl8z4hzP6wZyItIAeQkYHVgCBZwIlgg38wG/k0Zyny3bTGdku6lqBU8RowLHF86YESAKQJMxlWoMCAc@6JBRJQAYG0KKwmntUHLgIZ0jLBjGwLpR0lhw/HHmsoZ6GastwLrEip@C9E45GIaI6wFgV51bZGI4Z@obL1EiRMvEnTs15NsK6d49UB6WSBYO2Ydj9AgIqOOaZ6AN5RD@KbLaLdGbkDKl8DFBZ91x2uEbsgmi4R0CfupTVHfS65zOGwD/Ic7C0gxMTsAzKXJukDpC6EY@UIQSAM1@rZAJCiArlqj6wW0V4kHUKnQQIvolhiRvVOGqHcD1ULaTZ0Qah6GMaZ9PslqO6sFktXk23rIok2vOpYrDIQB78ygfpQgGiaUJdTZYpYBJDuGBpVU6d@znruYDFpXLwcBknv2VgF9C/NGeReBySLNTUHoHEwrNYdqLgHwDE8BzEnPF7xHLK260THAZTLEVSvkOggJQCyTzQZ2wML9DEXgmCOZwhpFG6EWXMGrEzUymikjnFMlgilScuE4haZkAUvLFCxtSctpBrGbTvEQVAheFRbVQEuVzo1NECRG1lmm3tD7QIxCulHUNtZQHShCrQIEGooluOBtuNpzEa1EBi@63aAx6iKBlUDgs7jaVHaMeWB1VRraRJRGvlmcN5nNmsNhwzsQT8BtB6mClDHui9t9hoc@z2P9VuT0WjGpkPIAHsAvsYtt9MBpn1tDXsAgg3arDVrQamEVCLTSG2XJFBruJTk4GvbAj@OBcnef/o11rWA2lAjdwBT4vR5AoZDSgKRwnR4be2YQClMQms4I7IAmCBEx3U1tG@7lkc8AtpMUOIxMs/qUomA4tWZy6ABah/AnKAROMCyIHBEqUL4GKG0MjEYlcj8jy0HSkwLmBHKOmQf6qN7rAO6f6iyRuXObLWs4Viwh0tSzHZCCs3RQ1RoyFYVwDSvJ23fA11sAQMJvEo@54RqcPOchCsq@qRnmShiRQMD6nTHClRYxgVKf3YjevBxsRS7/AL9LGDwQl6Dw5BKAmp3JBsmY5QgKBTtVg9F4BiFDGkZUMhGk5vJB7tw9KMBUztB3IiNDtJG0pKBFeKxHoYKd/8mIG3YR1jVBQv0umBxC2jTG6yA7AZI9tthWy1paiALbwM6cB13BVQgZgAXvSy6UF4QM56g1DD7ATNScfEW8gjl9Lzti/UXVJ3DoTuCksGFzgwlGc@yEHe5vJ0SC6oIBdrNizUq1BRRrOfHY97mGvahHURFDEsq6JMmSAoQYrwFADLP5TGGEKZST7AEfpck8TkzQRXqOBaqpOZoxoFA8qBWhohmzB6NQAxeYN3Aqx6/DtGIT6EqMNttlKxIDir3y5FryNH7k6Y9XW5mtNBSe@lJF@aIdbCFMQJdAwpRLNrxokqZ7ClkyElOusNxkoLypwweyZMGWR7rQKMFKoKHIGhOZk4rJi8UMTnB5Mm4U5AVMGBArpqxL5vD8TJ2L8EOmWZwDuWavsqsC7W2qsJTRTvCBB2SGjqYI1AvoBCCll0stpsmewPSY8TU6T6FRrWQ3rqWCeKynHYQlyAE4hJOr8aj8EYtMqihWg1TgN4p5VRJLBDwPSlBAWWwSCZF/YkWpORxN1JnuOXEoe4BFuMaiMKuAhUdKoAYIWODzmG37HFDaCl37vj6ylalAswGShSIzbYSVu79fhQNJDV41kgJEZFoY/dkjGUjpkB60fM1xwa0JeDUSpVdjXsjKHH0fS2BJyCr5CAn@4QV@fzEPp@0lzPaQUv0JGOpA13Jbo3lsgSVPy8NlU1UjS5QFZT/KFIVmRfDE@gbzEu2mKGy8DayPNR6KwKVUA7HEAPBqytJxIMKuzlD789afaEScBMUdi6NmoD@uWipB4IoIXQCv9DeKKkcCBYHDoc93Tv9pCLKIndMNm2ntGDRd1tmn6y30bvsh310eP947/hrjRUw@naztGyRtDOFHFa1k6nadSbJjGaUtsMw5oAfNDbDxoCLfmRJODPVnYZUpVkLKpepT86j468skwQ0ISQHxQBmvJdUGu4HlC6paXq9pUqYdeNxiDII4vtl6iHzYQYGRB3dTR@fp5PXrzHzlpEaCnvErD8xOQDfMnno@OE0dFxSwHynZofXiBQWtFDbwf7PuSns08fnY9Sal5EhVTrEMh8fPTw4rhDYnumdW/2@Sl6S3hh0KXPU1oDn@5O2Ja3yA@IPTC0W1@aIoz5NuK4kcKu1QOB53rI18AEANnE0l6n9gZ80rwe47y@njWzVVsAB9E0QlvXKsD7U@lBEQ3hgFdfClu6qWpQc5pVVYLWyxgpcF6utVjZr5TPFcLXVmsfZDgMdkFJsu77eOAKnc09FG22uRQq1WqB/8ugG4h4pkdAUUH3MvD7TKC6vL2HrRbVZ1EvuQwvN7Vvac5J4MpOVZDLqd3xqLY/anCH/B1N7HEsp/K0r4Bdi39s7NB74nkVHHXVgUKMBm@BYM406ONDQ8oBHHLfvdl22A2G4duhHCGrT2mTudV3nRg6ZaIlJjeDIBchf7K8xh1DX2K@p4Uihws1VPuphOt4lSGk9l0YiEYUIVJL8ay/NCxPINU/3yeHXD6AS0bOpVGBO0QUkCIUhcqGpFbIlC6ZCRJrAZ2UCg1GMG6Xdd1BDwwiYaCHogoB7c@eVliQxteRK/ytR@rJ7g@Iv3dkSa4ENZy0whEh2@OTpo8MnB4/3PjsbG9nswncmVcwB4SC@JuhCWo/TDUvrDi@amCwEF4GyMcLiBVJgAg0Uvzt84o1AcGvoReMIrOEaPv4T@7Lbc6KespyYS3RVXzotzkKPsfBxryIgNLTbfWyMjPiwGdbnyD@98XjolZJJKOW9SVODRmvyZcvtm90khYOKod9P6th0OTzCfg1vVQhAxptZPATv0wLVYUYdh2Z/4ELjhYbiUDSwGAdPnVV9u9uDtjCO11kjRQs4mFKTbEMLAdrKySBtJIDpC2gr3n4@yZy1v6QbBc7XesrIJGXf20LxB79bHQuaTjGorYAUytInO7tzdofNQEojpGUgEabtiCEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9GqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDrajjD4yILe9xEkNV37/OzMqYOCfnaHcMOBsNqsXtPrSpndDLIj/Ctl4N6F5CHv@hbAu2QE1qQ3WyPP2uZNcdY2qXS1WXI8GIo6Rx2yx3ugSL12QV63rXDZwwDJsGNyZ8FvEj2/Ta7oEOpjUAkfSKkkFCioaYH1koiXCkovqofAOSC3QgHYvDeDp4MPP4fkCDa6ke9tN@pRXz3qNdhJ6g2BiNTH3EIp7WH/4Bhqx4DzUUpD5qKQZpdWFLvPTY93UkIgMejoh4e2WgCBOuODjmgnGGwFJqBQ1DwHyQF8hb2lvXkvIzb6gdMgQsIJOx9Ag3Bo0KALcgYC84Ts8YTwmMhmMUnnjnvpILSmxQpq0x7zPn53MsLBPLsdTht4TxvcD0CjxIXkOo36Na0W72XlgSkV0Ag02cAauNiVANoViQKLkmDyEUNsC3rYUQ3FKqXiwAnAV9m9fZBiLYv3F6kDbEQBSx2w6HiU3FO/njTV18DNG3QrTPxeeACbMv3UJwD1RAYj2NRLInpASTtxB@TpOfW3oON9X92VhrNxD1IMHCabFXdoOcttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sKrq1tRUtRavRBJjugmkXTXfRFAfTXTKpZEJ/GpooRIJM6FqjEGhXj17XfMhTpY48MEXN4bU9jJm1UildT5g1XbwNfCuQFUB58K3iC@BElUoFjYoiVy9xqAb091Da95F3TlojeyhI8GVQCPi3oEGaiADNe9TmR1YZ26abKTKojKDRaKGKGRtFz2qps/rZ1Vk7fnYdTWBopWxWoH0IwmscG2jdkTsZguJWy5RUkG1KLV2ql5uVaCq6E4sV1D5EZCrKRwUlbnJax6IW8FTs7CwKJBXUqbV6I4I3TRiKEhAK8OjY0Mro92NR7aoA8TeVuhKPQlglmgCxXIlGgS4tJIJHicYeAc5ED@0pkBIKJlRx4TEFEpA0JoXF9evWsDcbhT0EvW6gZWMP@nwwHgoDSfGwlHzNw4cVuoWWvq/3cn@g3GLnHepLwxmX7hLH9Cy5MDHEr3cv1M7AHZvJTzVoNGmh6jK6FU2qKtSE5MIhUbIf2x4WYdOx3IkX7mlc2QGKsYPtaW8CwtKfNZMArrKHktXquSy6fQ@gs2CYB6sSHLFS@biXD6Dd0uBGIYpaCQ6WgHZB00lskIs41YT3yuiEBBc9ft98Njd8pQWxlSkMS2FEdtdxR5YKJIEQEk3@oKlCUpWJGSWH1PN1Y1xCuFKVhg1v2wKJ@LDvmkRbLq5D40HDQSg8tM8hyLHVlvogPzogHjWeFyOrndyRaHDWHfWghoDUoCQ2gtwaCIek6w3b2ngKQaUYVrhhR966A6XzkrUNw8i1sp2S74ZcAcTuQSZhq9SBJq7vpOrgqIhMPuDdQn4b/cnRgwPed0KVLVav2I/WGLjtCeiVot10bDndBDsAfrIdd2ADGfzwr8/7x6475q18@FjXM8MbzfZg0jepz2e5W2ZjuJbbdPvUFbQp6Nz/ZOSZfZN3Qvmue58@Bl3/2elJRSuFPCXNi8HGuLEfcnW0nJ6H4TFHGmb1h4c8zpjydlbGesufjIZiRjjk0GEipqJBHvn2ebT3ixSOoQj7AtoPcBoa6MqiF4E@A0vhsUgecWoazugRlld66hrt17bBAn86@eOK4xzbK90g@4txp7NgnSbrcxVFU39unSFrPkVtoY0YRinLPeF8tQU/YUA58hNMW1v2J4RXMMWgZ/X9EcRjUExwlAzq9j6qT9A2QU2czx2zQJEe4mAISWgcYmMt0DW9G90WUKaGKvctRbaonEAdlkTNRdpOMtHFXaaS4rhiaNLj0tOFpj31nuxW@YA1Np1GvNWW5J3v2w0AsVst@7OJ1nnDmKLRwBtBJdwgBCWThu1vJDWYhOFRn7pEQcqSl4RWw9RIqWfT/EE96REROkw@O5t@lDI@g8YHzvnavpPsWmWMbi216Jv3Q7d6IDZYfLpIMsiHidNx@22VD3pB/jPeXMKMEFMNgllnJPDBxh75E85snMQiJgaCuAzNVbsBdynrqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyxN@eJizesBjXYheYN@/a4zq61sdvoYeLHk5GzPA@Oq5SjkTnzJDFTpcL2jj/@tJaqcwjSwMSBrALPrak/jRL0YNB7cLYqmHC@zdgeU8VOEwtsTK@uAVJTGvMA9AEGj6DMgohEihD1N9abeVo6FjQ8YxZi7s0GCWYp11qnb47HlsN5i48mric3H/YR0VQo@rtiDKHEUjTQAoqmjW6AYpmdnD44OD7WgEO9WPQAB2RKUOzMVg/0jXWJ9ikZTnyJfdSOso8wjIKtcAmKFDQmGiI8MG8ZmBuaExA7ioKuNYqBpYJjKS2wpuErCsgVLkEgnDXVGhONAmAxS4E0EbDSSvyfObzlJPAssSiLEyWB3LE7JaCtrWgTx36leVBvkBoKXqK87UlTZCvbMRJf27pC/DOyBzgWDE0m0gIhDbUa2wLpRr5lVnnLPq@l1GI9vs3q9TIf4YeAqNPTlFsxfdMU9OTDYSQgBc6HolXWWZrE68dAPbcYiuOnA89Kgm8B2dGkObtZSuVtQ1YCZNXXYMEd5WUkV0wy5Sj6U5tIhNBMqMUZTYvzpULJekaN7KXJ4ZAcH4EgPTgMGeOpZFsVpiuKjxkH9NwcYdO5xJ66nmc3@zR7tdO3@UywoLIuCcIISD5lwtGVsWAQ3bA8QznDzJhPWeYTgQUlyJ0qGmhJYcrIIqawKyQmkdJAKrI3b9BCZtsGIzaQccYwp@@136YF@fjIBWQfiRnQYZ2DhIaYnoKi40yS/cbb4vgvuvCGQfJiSedVL@RwOK5z2s65S6NIgamR0vQs6plB6MF5/2bIju316LHgNcCB@zXWYecNmh16rPBAgylimJ4sqJteaNiQnWbymF7UY78i5sWpKQvRNq3OxOnSmCaamfrqFp9qsUCeO82mvc4rEAFnm/nvFd5AVmLJM7SMpvulBzt4oFoE@cnbRPOkL89qYgt0h0pqDKHE@79@ow30v5k7PaivsD8zMDRAU8CcUjtrM0sExQ96rM5Y3u0@6dsmEYZMt4FsmSNIktkPDKtB09C@qoK@McCBCpHjwJv4AF10A5txzPk4o/9eHcmqoToH5HZrnd@lWV48KhpUguZim4jAdS7bokAkZHkmWFM@sBNquKPAvR0pfyoWI2bm@d6bjCf8CerwrZloD/HeVDaFz1TWbOoWNEjNpm1tyPKReT5pu@rwvBuoxbkVfuepp5FlFbQSMcjcQOPq5PMEjuwuVPf@e523ef2avKTXbVzhORNvqDapbd/mX1QQBhtiGPX5c50XW6xUCgzrqWb36fGenCigA6OIORZJnMGqhohmL5G5bzZnqAr1PpzLgvkKIHEqrXg8lV4zYD0crg@P7VMKXyyuDj3VWpweq3oeknyWrMr75ijBYt7sLbkK1ZU9MPuq0Q4Z1wrzVdMdbngNRkopjHWB40QXK3NuTn2skFqTvjmamzaw@BwPf3BiXT@3qDZEWW65fdvDAt1fJzX9OXfzuHCeMj1C8yrsVZRsQ0MU63E1MK2WAm5rjHNR17DVe8g0PgcUZ9qG@ERz1xGr5V7ivVaD6EFjmD9XV2qvV2L1HvJJ7bf6JlTla2uEhV5H7NW8hVcvbc@ix2rCnq9EdNzqr7RfLAV@f2K4f/A2zvbsvuuxE3puIlB3BFTgz9U8HaalbToq9bKHzRvEkD95Yp6hZr/r9nOFbtKEx9pcn4w6KPrF@32FXCCkdP0WIeVrQK6ji/da0X6eHJ3flkG0/muEE2dDxg217CpJJQZ11qcO2gY4Irg6ZQ9TBQqpJXkf4pqIcSzn0pz575@j9lhHWr/2GM5IowYFDwMUC2AYj7iW/fPEltkcW/v9hNINsPnbEhHK3PO@BfUVPW9kKTNS@geG0FOp9xdRnf7Emlgr2xpHzZcWLiPe0M54f6RSIhnbYggARx1wzUvg67VoHL4X1lhV49dGYWJCq926XZtZFGpDUMCH2Hp@CoanaLgZoutMhgu5utBAc443k6w39Iu0217ADl0@VA4VblGWFlR0z6J7Y6OJN/Jw5lklk0qlhA4TGspZ@NjUmEoHYV/a/LkQMdnMY577xeG7Uci4Og4iS3hu41oRZKxr25PnYjHp2I41nuHzPaVp03X7H5JTIFTbNmpjoFzSHN5NOXZD3RGrU9i898LDPo9mZ12/Ba9tRPMS6IPt5k2ZHh5req/cVHE0dYAjXYufm3twQiNXt8WCy7mxW4jP6u2v1yVFh4iuFbT8xlLHNVS3afVN/prmMpvgFbX0RniLQkOMAuOoMR8rno/xR5aE0nAGxLLb0FDpWQOLPjco@mb75cTzX2s9TV281zlPLauVnB5YrXUehjbIBQefC4PTIWVp7DrQxBrjBEJsqvRxiqqwXSeB/eHElUQ@HJhdi@9RsUlSzvsscJoOb9nNjat7L0p8ak4Lgs17mNezBBSqc2vm@e@VAB/PWpCvk8HtPW5Lhb@F3aDvUdrXzY29WcU6Pbfn9Kwen5AefK0rHMCPY76nyCbUAetuD@fIDYcLc@fD9Oy7/f770BNFIxeUrttZidMBrqrFJWEfBHdmNsFBvG7tvzPHXHagYW2p6VkTqJc8d@wOLZW@1nntY18Pf66Tof7o98/bibSxqQ8U8d8/L/xb25Zd0x0Ph/RqDPsTjx4UVKXF0LfpTR0@54VmW7qjrvbaHTQ1YamJCTE06L5axDTtcauHi9A5Z1tdt9nq2bch3bTMsWOfJ/1eH/75Xm1XpIzN1AdorfVtIO9opiG/VMLuJ/g6XJfpogOJV2uBYYO@sqqTjtZ7q0PzvOXxDlE0sRL2CYdKI18VXqLl9KVXE3s8BxqaJBX08PKRCTSsw11My1irWdHii7kYFtM11nIpKemokKtWChQefW3/0sIEulARS6f5Yx1C4VQSRqEJLx9CbjGpiDoI7VDXLdgv8NfCbKiVlZzTm3S9mwKT99i3QUXDx/puC5okHeq1hjrLdMRrHZmNfhJXT8K7ATrXxNo4rJLdOK5C/vS@aro2vBrwgqybrO1D69tDjz@Z2lk7GicmSUFbfHnIkNNmtroxLTKmbXX4KAiablMRBy6N04IOorZwTB870VGYc8WLCy7H7YJQV/ts7tn3u05tWTn/aHX2B3Wm@tkTq2viJO5H9hhnga7gCmLZVfOWboX91Ynp2V@dQMrWMRtuBcFHIkfhPQPwawW8x2bXbn2ykBEBkoLAYgopfy2wP1rdzIvLnu3hHKrAsKFjClmOMzFyXQPaDSt8LnfdB7tgzAsQX1@50veq7nV3OMNlaDMybepZt8fUyyre65qO62aXbUTicjIYTjzxWo0DzdIK90IPzsneu7QBuPoKRCvrmf3x6p7qUJcraGGiUpwb12njX7f7bpd9vZBioLSBEobK@QrGuQ/V81OcGjRyVnAixf2eI5/Y0aGOeMJeQd5aaabajj3e3JszHuM0If@NieE1By59SD7Cp3bvQyGop6sp8uh2XX@@5vmW@h0478SdjFoWGoONTMLNAhGrte9Pa8alIi5uxHIZbqVtHL2B6tB1JmN1NHE21gq5jbVCiU0LuRAbsNhXDx4/U8LcQNPAb9NCLWj8Tbz@bG5aO2dgiclsBxSx9XJ00bfflnjA9106pjnIt4TZw82hWiSuH7ir2jtPZyNr/N4NJhD@k8EDq4Ujh7fG/cR97Dou1EZDEJSDY4tvJrAw12N1QAz2CJfLA33at0ZzQmDXVEJc2zCHVhPytz83vU9dxAE/MMfmmqqI@gap/ReYbuUVu9@0Ri@p0y9kXtekXUToE2tKbYv1DMPLoDputbhKjP1xC2VkYcTGG7quw58kbVPw0h9vlipQFdDj/cfKNZzhv9AvsLJ9tpjUows@UcRq890u1qV1ZDXdPn9umJbk2HxagDmyLS/5CDdPILtchqmgfXkbZUh@owyZN41Ak70wPRqnX93UmIPUpx8wC6hnjloujoQJw4YJOqEdD24R08GiAT53oAmEn4LEMlsTsffibWj1B80BPdY2GEK5eWw1cblRk7YJGZvTm5nJe4bEHgmhSV3BzgK@uMJCnWOxp9AaUW6vthbaUYtUtYf0IEm9dric5uuojm21XpvYa@YSveZ90wvukObkEzKu6asOFSPqRU6atIR@ZUlanL0GCk3fUse9EbT5k@NN3dv@/i0rxkMmAwsHmRdHYdaqrq7Xo8S6q8fTA@E6slSxdyDIkmAfQa4fqntrNU8ED/@j@19OQiXcyGX8PU1AdN0@gg/IT0aOeL0PBz51vXHHnh4B3rjuYJ04wWRlIQi8eMlA0866REDuOZM@733ohqZeDdrUHFNp/1pV7ZO4Hluq5VyotMPc9GaKXL6aLLmHm6GOrbYqNljAkQb1kb@wLPAm3isGUMOyEed76klO2GkuI2aAriLupS8ZQN9yx@rQo3dy6D09fHR0qg09fWX9tNfD9Rg39LiFHRuMQirUJfXSHIXGO/mMtLbtjZP3T3R1/9Ghhh7W0JuPaKjwwpG5hdfafk@x9aiZNNe2gtDVGq9WED85ffwoPl/7yWL7vZE7sJSw8/7JSQLXtnz5ZKVzOPRDKB0dd7o2@OGBrisr2PeZQ6OD66TnipjWQTq1oDUKzPgJ3/DlVuWq5Q6t9ulsaH0KlSdKcO89o8@tTeQT88LuYilkxbWEooLKilouo4QmZ0Nj2xoF73X5eW4PUVq26JXkr7XTUVBzSCdH6dXaw6YR/2UthqXETIQPC6SnbnLr2FahZHR7aEqa3i@KmK7r6@h8YnYgX1l2bWYtelg1Ptx3L95jKNkSjRc1sFLHwFWqfetU8rw6ANGdxAd2zwtLMDbXToPZBCCwzq0s8JeWMzMdlcayNqkXJQiNk9o2evm69R4DUsEMnwvcEHrlGF8wq57FWmRUbon4dBQKsr9///C2AMeClpt9ffzkGXtqeri7yWaPYYyt98B4rhm9VLHfCrfWWzuc2h4BKGMjvO5wdXkusRNz1Had2fT2QTha3IpVO21WHMDCL/Jk9e2pvaquavF@raerpxndFjdfx@HOFvTg8K43AtC7b/8LXU@laE8jfOsp/nlLzvgFnMXQZM5wo7yw0@lhIBpaqLdoYKGsbI0@sqY4HYX3Bq9q1K@s33Ib6r48ufF1PccTJ7zTrJcQewXw5Xh8gZSn@dsBx2JOPK4oizvOh5eD8YVQuB8ZX8MEft@8YVtiqRI4BKu3xAIp3LYI9CYLlxVKBALXrcWcSkXPFtld3Pe9BFJRoRhxAxbaNDC8228WlKCW5MdeY9tXYiVSqaRf42osuSQzsVIs2P2R72AIMeHea5BKpp7rbHsMLtv@OiZGe3CzN4x0LxD2ejYFX1oyvLC0LBZ4AZLbV08Pnx6cnO6dPjupperXsiKWMXLcHAdi8xe4fpRuy0ANQUjIU76fKS2E7EN0tD846myeny4GKVtKWmUhafNEyXcxzPaV4ySTtJ4vqV4DfqrMYyNXENBoxWH7KaYcE8sxS3wZXJ9IKm9z0DLFCblYYqlVEQ9Nz4NkCfflEwrIlaXT6MojFltQQknqum5bxOhZ7PbLj/Hh3uGjZ8cHzEdwzkaXdnvcqxSzfIdSlHuqBfnUsWlqQIVFRZAo5FWlEn0YBcJEtSgr0SpK2h0UOB@8@dTB9Zci9A6LbRN8oGA0yJTkf/1G8jqq4Sw3BfxGfaSiTFAePbBTXBn15z9u892z/f0Q/GM4RgMq5LTuXBKrHteseUSKUlEdrj@Mg3arpuWNwTbZ8wNOJNo8HbjykrYyWtrmRqGdJ/jJKmIXIj8iYhB/x13sLsEdhaCtd2Hj2kaOQwc3@FlkZRxhpU2tNLaHJ40AzzOTdnAH1CfOmG@iIZbcR4CPtEDEJNg2Icv3e5dDHqO7W8DKTatrO8xzQAe1xiX2EvgMuyRKfIGtqlajN4L4oPkRM2pvPOiHPN7YEchLno2T737tO8lumYF5mroPX78ivjpg/lVu/jyJeX1z16B5/GEkcKcvgTWPPKA50jt0qIrDFzLPiYWbG/myk9kDyJoLojR65zHwpwoidw4nVvsUMgpYDHJJLGDm8Vmjegy3Gislk8hGOLyj0aRNa8pnUCxtOZbL5jJ6EpBUL3yAtEdwF1eHcYCKUgLGly7sYeVFE9hrd5fJqNJYlVyZ52Zy2/k8Lb8IEN0Gv9JlD5GrMQgDQeYhwK0qgkEFE9cVDIryKKpHURS1Xah5yB1rKPx2BCFkFgNicRpZuOnsFE/XGY9m/tZ5TTyxJlSjbAtAqg71DpkUWRJrbp@4Y2CZhdXGfM0tziDitRzuSeXx06NoxzrkQe1maZovFfM3qhflS8Nyz0GlU8sVZjhv5ecI4gRBlORVLFv7nJ2Nz5x6kvMmAzb9oWDZMDM7YP5nye4anuXp3ru5X1lsebcxJBa7d@K4qLs9hMSwmJE00kk9p8yTlMmsTJJIkYgGkoO7KLyB6EA0gZhoWfZLd@jt7R8cfvno6cmNPbnIZ3TZG0jy6m78TNUStXpgiIaTtZgl9x8mTx7ff@hnxBzpXEgCgz4jUqJvSsm8SYYg51N8l5O2CsPl1K3H@DlfB7iMb9rYhBoFuoGHnvqAeGmanfqQJssvR24UVlErm92E0hxeMgR6n690uoFqTLm6rtV3q2dOJHqTE1YUhM8j2g4WAjCdeTvbSWT2m4nDhAWnvJ3i@TReuCymV5dFeTuNW8PgWsuxez7fFEdYhBxC6fWjAREpaUnf69rSd8T18PnWTQY/hY5vIhPeOiOEcC61ieIhUKf@gXYoReYbz4k913rQMOrbTcnfsoTvveZvERVsu8a3G4kpkti@nEccE0fcTUtTjcbUYwpKO4KVYJu2cfPhKRIUaNTXnk6ggfbUHfLtbGns5IHlm45dEL8PJnwQ1mJfngzAX4dexxb1Y4HkViEwUDIaoMr1J5ASYhe3aRz3yYP4ariXm0i4NmhnY1NF61nTtt0F2R5TEiDRPtL1Ogt2esNE085uTlSmPJvnwsai@DGuXwuT/YO2@5vOETBrpmY7bWsai15GlVId4kf76OXzi6gir@Il2nZQ7MPXXt5/MEA/r2@WJOZYlE5/c79V0qJYvCklwG4ZMN84xz9Lo1jUep5ERyJVUBc/GY8egRHUiFhnYA5ZbOLwzYU0Rp@xs5iToN1Y1Crfn8xh8Tg1keBFDhqjkB0y8fo7ZjozFktWgAnQ1nPa@HptD1lN17Q6mCkShW3jGTf7oHHhRh2KBO1cCFIisBVkIWg4AEa8kGicwSEMuku4f8qItmha4UxHflBz30WaUKpZ9Q4LHVW0qDnKxWJJZOiiVCwy4L6b4lBLAtgbcs7X5YG6YiMAoBk0aDUpMhfkNyVehOKNcEQ@ETsIADqR0J6C/sYCDGDNd/xr9UZ4xw4cKCu4F0rp2enDRkFJyizYiaA7stvYHcW3xQ0abeIgAyimyQWv0TJvo32MwXCLqQbf6gB3QHpIBUZeEqmRMBmWD@6c86aub@R6EVDkAvjMYAUglms0fHC4l5o/MLjCbbWw/9nP8GhQObZ9N5du9C/i0WyqDA@9nGVZ9tH2mapu14xsqnJvu26a4zOZmcnMzoMLq9dpHnaTZ7LM0iyTTO4YuVfnQz2383lNezWty7VCJXFef3rOnj797G3jrSJPL2byWYzlI2z/6I2sQwIipTwrMrxXXnRm38prQytdjgLcszM88lPOy8lkLVqHPzm9gIt7qlW1qna3/vatUstDmqazswiepMeO7i0CixmGcmLbdpKdDb12G263x@r8LNgIv@LxmMqEhVrjdmww7ZDddM/qdicH5ozb25EJvh6ORdjHX3/@/DkantPFXh@L8Bw68@MoNcxshBkp489/snWduHra2P3zbw6S1ha@jvD1nevHaD7Rsx9tbX10/34mkwAqcfPTrz/92t7eXuZBIvu0lr2bUVNbu3/2p1tbhrFrJLfqnqfXo7Xz889kI5WRtT//UbTx9OlXPQ@zBa8008GIzwLcOupU5@w1XOcdhn8yv26HzCaam53XzIi8jgBbR2b0a0QYL4UV0pLC1xbTq3fz/@17R68i40jVSD4fwXsceRXJFSLcCAb4SvtfF5FqZBe95a4js2SlUgFj/r/9ewhf/TLAQZfZLjyqWR9WbhapqhUK8iZSzYFBNwyI9//6xjdu6fa5x2pwyZm8Id@tw7VD166E@z@pqWRyybteuKPfYcwZ98aWiy@bvxx4MbPsQKv7uBaPx@uaCpfWoEBJXTfOqMMmzFrU3xIJrMuM27CQ3ZxPhA24PY8QTwFTEV9xs7AgVuMWz5f9PV9xlZ//Y1/HUiS3dc96UK2CKDSqxk41TtfWWanEyZ9k@YLsuvewRyt6JkfZC/ZIELsqpwqGnEgk7jXwoGU2RZqq08icgIzTiEUWKBth8y8WtoowPxib@/lQfwd4/cX/9hff/4vv0e/7dP8n3CrLadud5A5H/qLKL1atytWRfHVGH/dYqlQoFZINdn0W26lV68dMT338JppNR08wjeSJnSl@D2ckuKpVfPho4Fc1wm2q3DS3Ey7V4IN8zIOs9seEZPKJGoEqWMwoUmsXdY4bxy98TfFitXuQTbKRL8r1qpE1jiDrdJkyrsh62x5zIyJFd@Hagh/94bqLncfCBp9bZMldyOuKaytA5fZrAVcpUqsl61YdFFlW9YHc2yptFUq5kgGZsh5weR3oyEVYmmh5raAZID7e1rbYMef1Oov711n81uuZpjWEkQwu3qrqTiNS5B/hqkoscgVX/e1O7S2wroi6JsppfFetV@MCI3hpjXv1uHp9XdM@j5fL4r9bDYxlurgJElK/VtXdzwFW7SZUDpSeWuPzXQAb363tVtx9urUGklitf16t7S6GFcHv3YujjL0HAKrbdRbNuNGce48p8fi2qm7V1qYBANdjDFoFkIHXu9fV69ru9fXuLvx36Xkt3mB7vXvjT6/5tcbP3J2KzVktWT1Lngm2qcO3lqyijZY8A0MV3uAPqiEpokKBkiI7bCcyZHo@DSZmlfQdI53MTj/KHYBqVKur2IKpqDU9l62rXFK90FhJ5ftr64WcoqEoaridBi6J09gLKfLi3Rf/C95n7774A6z3oVgWpUhyB5sHRd5KgMdjhz1@/Bjvx44Df7gf88tBG7R4jHYOfzjch@8nsOY2WBxAKDDZKOTkRlyfGSyyK@fyKBZ@6cYVjUb/yQujmI/yFjQuHXvhgeUvrbr@yS@tu6TImyKW85bHeJqkCJV7yAsoP1U0XuGj@Qp/j17j79UYf6ct/B2/wh87fY2/4zH@Hjfx99TD3@kr/O018Xc6wN/9V/h7PMbfsy7@pEgFlO3tu6l@qpXSz/VzMNgsNWKpXqqnt7ElkLJYapaasdTA1dtgsuCXApOd6rBUl6WclKPr4AiGMUuN0dSBVxd@HYAygp@Ng8fneqrFIJY@AOVH5ND7DQgy5UyqQRNSfmGBWqzpWkrL2XXcWLwm141igWlIYa1Re3EWreOOlUYxw5oza@vsBYt4oFKXI8mzsyTvHGBGpox7kF9fNxoHTx40GkkURWeP3aP5/@hoEP7c@B8cuY@P3IEL/6Ojo8fMqsbvxdV7cFWq8V3xuhuplu@elVQst76oiCR3755V0yqac3Eo/QbaxT/wmkOEd3XrTIoy0FQuy6QPlS8vypdlMgSfYGiUAw/CGzeAZVnoUWBT9hWqS7guLskSH2i8fH4WmLgh@fzyDNsF0OAL/qBwhj//Af72/7v@j5@xWK0O@k3s6no3RpeCP0W5ur66Fs@qEouJj9gu/NACvjHI1XUVjeTpCky1mFJXrq@5HTxjyi4HWMU4dqsUeO4RCn8kiJPi5Y/YP@wb4xbXGe5tbc5H6s/OpqmUUm76e@niKJX5hgZMlTKdjLLdrOn1P/sR7Zh8VyFP2Uy5rO8w/mFkjHI543/lC@Vywf/YjsWKN69q6q6eAwUnk1GUchk@7vpgU/AZgC0AWP8jC1Atz2xRuS9Hrg6PaC9hEBPZiIIp4oIhlqItx/H0iqhcku/ciYlTMe/uKXfuGMXUmzeBzXAIVvqCVaPRtkeNBtqn37yRGzKNnBez8J0qvHkDsiyquKPYEzz0BCKKqTr7yKhSnEV3BITIgzPTk8Yci57pmePxKPbaHiZknAbjyQqdSZBKuaOz6E@/@81vnkUrFVmVyTajIwCMhWV3d3OZajWXAXOuAJSSt6/48RzdeFFXrreTMqcGk7ejEeGkF/IKl41RdIcajt2tQgH38GJX1xHKdpbJKjGQrgooWtcR/HFrvVjk9iyTixXiRfGrbCmsCjoA/2H7NB3P7OR37tUZ/aarLhTJ5Surol9XrqwSdvNdl1vixDlcN2fduZMuAk0LqfKZ1Gg82DvdazQqsixjdQgPtCThLuFBN8NRtEYZni3Wa5i@@lk0WirfI@bQC1kWiZaFPzUKtQQrFIkMkt3BRbGQdkkXjf8tyaA3PiTRF7QFlngoPJvfTx/t7R@cJoxdUGmMh3v7CePk2f2Ijp/Z@Tc5p/H7@GDvwdEzCPD00cHeycHHh58ePHsK9h67nF@@BBbP@TtsWvF9yZ5LL0evTcsyrYllNS4nk8tX7KVtN2wgbH9i27bbHTHPaliWNQRv/lWGu2V75suX5mhIF3v3w2@/@@F/9@53v/vud7/97ne//9Mvvv9tuH8M93f5@7v/rpjF50@/@Be/9@53fhcs/xPcfwz3T376xW9@g9/0/Sdw/5eQ3Z@IO@SP3xLA@pWffvG9H/30i1/9Adz/Stw/uHn/2k9W39//1vobw33v9zb7@e6/h/v3OSzf73d/h9vh@4b/3@H@fvUH737jP/D/n4kfGn/33W/8CT7Exz//wZ/9l3ff/I@GUfizf/vuW997961vvvvWd959658a737z3@qp8OP33n3/D//6j37/r//of6L/j@n5@@/zf/eDf/6X/@tf/u9/@Ufi/gnc/wFMP/nL/wgM@3d/@EP8f@8P/@6Pf4j///lf/90f/vrf/cq/IcNvccP//a/@HX/@za/957/97e/89U@@8be//pO//a0//Ov/41f/z9/8z3/z3//B3/yP30TL3/rJX//xr/zVN7/9V9/6l3/1zS/WPL@98fnFe9h/8Y9g8/54vg@c90nXh9p88XPh84tQYx4L8Alw9z9795u/DAz@G4y9@/aPcfYn3Gv@PzZ08vNj/vX/AYNxM83okgIT3L/@7tvfRRL9D0Ai@Af0@k7wseDCP74z/wCy/vZSoIhVWqw8C0YhvgMtjJ1iUVSggfMuhfzpF//yR0EUv7wIdcENYvwOSqoFt@@gjHv3w2@8@9E/fffD33r3w1/B2kzNFBN7CVXf3PkMVaCafQ9/6DH3Pv7A42efQfzTOHWVqnH8Yp8Jx88@@0yavknidON7b8D2M7LiF@NO4MaEk@8m7HGmatgPN6Z84zZavwlHjWSIY7RxUgV2fD0lm2bTuN95iD1xvBMRPU13eH8iPskWnacSPub/uXEqsTj64Ree0OIbySDCiSi4UcpCNPHpNNR7SeoHYchtaBSJ4s0UGaZgOo1PoUUKBoghDk7346xSqcQxYIXjA58ctWqBESrxeAXSjaF5mESjgCCm9wkKhKzEj1ljpzLlAeMIr@qTIy6h1bGsG3K8UHkAEVamDxjCQuAE9sWLSrVQmVYR3FtOj/g0fp9wQmCV@LT6Fr4rBDOOnUoP3gIqhUo8Xi1ghJhInj2JBs@kLCWO0h5ncZEH8KYe2nuMfSTrBZmPaGwhwbhvfMbnvu/SGNtdcD@L74jk0N830r1DBN@iqEQsjLvfJVXxLtce0QPAVVVN0xjcqorY3APnKQcVp2jhFecQ4sQRxAGBBbAh5kWc8jdOHxB/pLLzwVe8KvHUbG9vS5GqnJaPaIQnDq320XmJH7HxhjeNSkzOFWW0tmjmN0@dtf2Uuh12HuzAU4f/wRZNyI6zMqG1HcXOvSjj8bGP4vy@d2@HfQSpp/fcTmJqPO1msHMdE7obj8sGxFp149LnIN0kYF8C9EbSphUaV4pLiQRjWiWCbuzo6EigRhafV6Q4cL@R1vEbBwImk0kEQmhaQkskxFujN1lowqCRq3hr20hz6oxkhpEpQ/umzNCKhZsjOrRb0fLt27eQWTQpo3QILUom5mcYmQI5ggVfhdnvz/yVBEamKPHmNNNz/BDsGJ2RpzBFYjG2o0h8@i5HIhjujRqFQhRNCuSJFtvxp@vkdMnvI6QuwiAEb@MVsorvuH/E9o8ePz54cjqs15lk0eGFVmM4cluW520SzDEMt/fkAZ/dbxRziEakVsOYT0sGiiXpoJQioXn44PjwpMQ4TUQOxQJISpn6fwUpiroUGQ6f70bElAYZT9Nw5RN8lubpjxnFNEZYLUuRloXNEmA4/LOy9Njr3nen0JZPyHJCz2ETTaEeVCZ9zS2VKm/1TF6CN31PGO77xBeJQunEOeDa7i4RTapeqdTrjUbI4JxUrYq5QUyXqicHpxDg9IjpRkpj0NK/yuSNTDaTNdK5XDZv6JlcMZPLFtJQ1@RSWcPQi5lMsVDMX0vVz9hUQ1xVMPcrfcvpjnvbOCNHPkvJIXps11IJ/BnpNDwBYkLP5utbW/0rFRE8I7a4wqlV1/B5pSIFvgQXk74ksS@BFVwQB86XYmKy2uFRWcwYwu0YYnzakKxnoXAr0hkwEgcnDcNXWbyhEEGTP3RLka2vf33MqlVoaquHD6UIyKoe8@fOqHZb62nETe3JyCLXLmNt@1MbT1rR2rY37JszKKEpTYpcX193ANLhQxxYpU8eoo3P6xbZNMF8PTWl///6xa/dYRV4czc5rEq7Jhgzu0kTjE0wZneTTTDy/YsYLo@syGNritulcTu56ln9joZrAioyATLkXbEfYFWEq@LiCtdsV3ANHU6KjylX7UrbbdFRTuW21nTbM80bz0CECk6oRJt9t3Ue9R1tPCET12dVjFxeFYUBCgJ/qYVEIZFNGPVaTC7J8VqdDvpSNF6e1K0t4D7LbKvw7rjO2FONYv06wBKSh1FXpZ04xpXA9F0JPEqO61jXO1fxltt3R6VOp3MtmYnmlcq/QU8sD12P9hYumU2oBEBqlsfusJS6lppXc08q2qlFsC2ZHZD6Vy0@Pa4kG9mCXK6V59/5nFyuX0v3BlbbNnGu/Fnq6kagXEq@DvycpdDbCk859ATp5MmDzOUbL1VpUlcNxFD9AGqXWn3X35IJ9ADJMFQjraZ1VU/j/xaDgf/392/A38AnhEob0ikuS3wCeQXi1mGPcAfosctOXZcO@7pvtdb42O@ZNHttf@R63i/g577pnHOnBzbfCyhw@sTEXf69gT3urfHxbDjAFY3W6B8NwsGgCQhiIeEe7sNj1HfdVR7y7NnTNal8HOy@B8Tg2@@B9@PDjz85Db1PD/b2P5Fy7P7RkwdLr6zwlGWPDh6eBp957uoHzQYgvnbw6NHyp3hFsGLGDtYtls37Bl3C6a93oFlyRxizubkxhcbnfGWW7QXTMfkSvJJ06i/XMhkW6KbFWnyRKbaTaAMIoS7p@aIkDZnjXrJ8irXdft/Egw47W2DZM3EZioUKQJ/O48SoL91Rv31pt60t6TGueCnqeJobIiF9AkAGkxattrbHEm4n1MYjCLFDv4mnqE/wmM81lvBCKzSO7G4P5Oql63uQmqbJ4P7QC8Jb4Wu82WLM4yC7Gy79m96liIR6njk2I4XynTv60xFwdrWQKpW6FrQEQAZWD6bAXWzCngG/myOUpNtJtp2Vcy35IdMaEXMHdKuuXWNefXjMCtjN3DLTmR1QdXVUFEC/M618BKUvaDeofdYM0HDOUkmznXFBF5FHslN@zVpld1j1UtfW9bgD2lm59De//WPk6J0kCK@ILss4LXdLlzRSI41iIVsopg2oIYqFTFbPZbMJ3UiAlp4vYv2hF/RcIVvUE4VMMZ0BvQxcs8W8FOFznpI7BBLeJQDrtPA4sl3SRLVeVYrw8R72OmYqLGIG3xMmWxBGxgOovTGt@9uxK7KRYXqKQSMEIJqsxSIPH@6nHj6U5fv4gaPc@ylZbuNHtpBK5e/LskUu@wWsVmWXhyngrg7ymH@kUvf3ZXnCAeCGiLLcw4@DHPZhyLKNH/t7Dx9iPB38MDA8eDvnLvyj73/kwZuDH@k0dYLI8qsAHPjb4xFlCNMD/MA40eUhd9kHN1n@2McnlQIIx9wfh/CJn9a9PVk@5B97e@iyTwnPclS/gh97dMkycAqWFlnugqE7gnIqy00wYpmR5RaYWjMT7PDwN9w1zxmbsjzjBEISyfKUfJutcxka@sIeo/nkk0/M3rhtdfk1G/F3C1ADF3s6OXjY/PjjZrfbHM32Dj4@Rpf9/U/MzmwyanabIlizAZcLYcDlfDBbvgDHw0bD7K90@Qq4OEsujVnDQtwa5ivASVxdjGTQ2AeXfXBZNVTGocE1AK9NvO4P4H3fbJKLf5ELvafNplxGRkXNjk5whTJDh6kmBmZr5Jbxe1rZYiwaiyZmtVyqXiYHNgAdLlW@pqNbY/g0sdGsXM1q00qqXplW8gafY9GJyWdTI2vLia3BXb2YLW2Zd3UjE5@WcPWv24myqKrfZTH9zs5rFnui3DXSmZJ8dveuKtf0@l1DL5Ry@c93JrKslPB5N50vgcdUFJqU@FBq@frdfDYUJJ@Pm0mjlM8r5Wsgxxjq1CaKk0YsdmmZ54qC6GLTB5LAD46dUTrtcic2TUwrHC82U8rTil7mGzqx1A1Ybdw9cNIauyMOsQvgpndTJTqaVtaLBRniTyZjigKSiYQIvOczqJ5/9fT89PQzkFnQqBRNsqf8vMOy@Pz4k30NWmniC3f90x6iBu2OtH0ULAsufFM63@oUpKj2CVSMoGX7drgiY@T2tYMpNJRRY/Ud/L2cNLEDj3b6yQKcE2iP8phxQWuZtnFwWhbDTRHtNjMrVTCZbRYjrJipXFKV3KhWK43KgJ8uWw1CfYXRjoFzMIcexz1YZkvBr3CVgnBoVFLX5WZlGpkCnEaFqfqLgdt@YcRb5TbuhXi/ch8DlxvwbpatioVn7MoRudy560DrfuJ4Zsd6ao1w0fjh0TbUO7h0IdZhlrLNzuhE3n3UoK/V6og5c8yeTAYxU602lUWr0CeSJvZVP8lXtJYGB5@vy50Ki32ulF/B52ibxdrafeVuptyO3WcNBWxSLzovOsxguUyZDimLISQoREQbOulWqVS/AjoNB3xeKgEiIo/PASbGBGDtNjmYytC@LrcqfRZT2ZQpRJ5MuVupYeg3@NhVZbmuqrU3damqqs@lKpTT8ixiVrxJkzbQZammbqRy5SnY6flMuQcZa34@LY8qQ2iyl/vwKfon@JIhswzkBKoBmNdvYu9@@RvKrpqtcLsygXrTBzWioTUq07KDW3IAS1TSFXCI1zKpRLYALbdsPgEVsgEVfi6RTmQSah5tdWrOgaUOCkCsH5MZkxOpaUrTE7qlJ6D0v7DbL5iSOI@BBkIkg4@xe4AH/IINZBJyJX3C22RK3NjpM8gFl5m7KrEpSIoyJgxo3mNDO9FDUMeW2acQiqKy9E6svx1DP9unk@FBrV4qHUyHXwWnmPrqbi6eT8VfK0o5tqVUPOuVVC1LVZQqlOrhFvCs6Lph3mRQgzweb@t5o1SrNTGF@VQinUpD8uzGm@6uXJXridRWToccumakxzAuMLguM9dG5nYN1KPxtGymF42ypNEsBYpRjxnFdWtNFAnnxwmA0lAIO6Qwi53J/qK5WDSaN6JRJVrGTt4tWfTNgYTjB2@DqI3e0e/KoD9Bg7tooIe5oKR1UamwCnUtYXuaZYpS5Eq6vrrehYZmkqargWLItsikatV7UqTEGOhxZ2LnjeQWYx86Cy6@W/2cv89wnizAlWhLrRqr09wUy8bWEfsU14DeZVFAzBwNaoaRrteMPNRvIDN9r4ahl7ELO4ITcrUqUN67Avx241VcPvEVNpuZcdWn7B3GuvFtiRIdWSb7XmWve7xX9r/2sf/sTJJluRyVI1fRSPQaflLkHq3ZMPiaDRYJrdrg8zxbFtDnbYQkBtu/8vtTSniwQ8wscflQqytvn9j9q0Ja5S19EFjX15HtJOWImPpe/soLIwt55Lj@XHho8aDuDVVXNotdgJHki6H3daOQfnx45DwYPbQYnwpfyDTkaoSldBVnlpdLwjbLp8LKxYIhG@eJCLsXKUfYuRrVSzRdng1Pip/nPy98/vjZ0bOjh1LkbOvNlovdw8wnC3vrfPmr4DGazkQZO6tEppVMWUxHqlZVfdfAXW7yDE9P7@g5NfWmytm3Sg45A1ze/fIPMtPdAnwboL2WIAuzcaNa1XcMpkSG7774A9zM4Org071HLOqZM/b3f/ojI//3f/qvaZJP9LrsUS9kPgI@0ajn8pGrq@HV1TVc3C0bqUc4Upm8Ambe761H5jPyS0nT3MnHM8Y9p5wUfvW8rkQ8NSJ69/PZiPdGOBmpAjj53e9kJecwCyIHx3bW0O/tIlPowUIeNh/ltbwicEXh8Ys3jMFHq9rudm2DTMkkK71V2e5bdZe9xe7rt@oWe1Gp4pCrjst//K7anWq1ilBYtBpP7kSZkQW32nW5HmfU1QvNv8@tHWfnbJGjz7ZYseiAveXtiAGCsx0P2ng7Dv2sHc@DT//L2nnpMRmHMJLJdpt2edm1WLYK@b@TBHTOlHe//JuGkfv7P/21N403jc8MaLkVizndiPxM/9nPwMOGded@s4u6s3GBOBqC5hpbc9Kv1oKWIh7/3GHcv994w@Ya6gx214EWOn5JF6jnUNY0@GZG7Rh528FlqQnSmmmrEaUsSYF2SVrxqNtKEAy2g7uwQ9mUrqQvoRNUpqwC4lL60hwUWAyg@nRbDa8/GQ1pmnuMwun1BLsDQSCGL@HOUVu0nFbIXBXEVHLnZlCOskdUI52IDSzPw32ooBaRvgRBxI5ZeLisiSu/0aftgJDX0AvhSQ7tGsRdh7j7PECDbGOUeu4hwTh2PJADmrP0JVAGiAo26AjM3gUPZRAsXwICQBpiArBdZ7ssrbArOx4vzze5usYpw7hrmOmvOpUwGEJr4ypnP3AZ/YEVaOx4RgvyhchhUM9Clj4QDoMPaVZA58fg9IVKFy0Lf29QAIu2YIlR0tidO3OsKhW7rTBKEcI/t4fYD0X54KzGFYD57aWP2iU5wXD7sLJvG7AdUDxO6ALXqXzfsHIoKJPx81qS4P/eTIscuZRV5FDGBIj84qWiBSSDwEh2nocttlthupFXWIB8C3BvEVK0QVXQCDybfqQZn/mO14DhzyL@DsggfU7DfXuCb5eXHTOo9ia4/SxuPsOFgVguzLeXQSl2OPZDB6EgKXaffHfsETRQaEjV36sqltYVDDbf24vwoEnARobhbNysgi8Khb4ZvE3clUnEs0U7S7RcyFBv6Dq0jRNtOYETnYEjQEaJ3XA42hPnErcrF3lDgcMYebQTDnI@YkzbUtE5bxQWxyibI2jF@rRJMKursdagzYwiixGj0a49TgBOoUCEcBO0XaRxs28NAKUTy2K4k5FXSia7oBVNmrR10WMb@Kr30IaqxPGS4ki95KV9bidPcbtV1e2ACi0WgkdQkcLix4dDxTZBfdc9Z3373OJdtrGFZfQeA30flNYEUHZ@A2FL2DtspBMsBc4J7gvuPLzy3FhIhMJuxWbKzXda34o1MEffUJ1kj/C4vAvTCdGXrjeSaOJ6M8/fiIO2k4BvLRC5lliCX4ni6t9gbwlJbClSod0sNOy2H8agwelvxYFG0MWtC4aNVQnrGBCaLX9RO5ZiSO2XqAKgsgclC3flGo9KuBUDYDJqx1pQ9ISAd9hHLG1I6JHvkyL2NAEYmPWVRejgBkExHd64DRmj8QVUIFegdA7a4IaLgAX7YXifu9FMO6bN2ZttCXBY6VBcFcaLhf@RDX1g6UB@pqRvgWMOMFyByVZMjgPYuKzIHHQQfjk453aJZEmJ3YSUYAhBkBqgkKrgn6fJQvuKS@Bw3/T45pNi/67Ly0uNNpKbjGzN8nCvbQ8PCU0OuzboxG5ybA2G4lQjG0@zE3DnJpVvsY9Hx96d0qGtxTsz/pakjlcRkxdi0Y4XxcrxAreS7g5oAxrc@cUjhnpo0zb0rZiYb8H5z6gnrnz@KyH/qYXoNQJhDMFME7NEKwHAEs3WeaJz2S4LhwsqkAAcctHyLXHzxpH/MfB8kz3sBD7cMS0r8L@b/XMavwRIMu86nUfNU@j7nPmf4ntoTyGQY12yvdHInMXIXUHfyMCxGak9bAbVPrmAEaoZdsV3ErSntVl9Ifg0CA6Vmt/kYSPcXUa62gyUbyuJ7lPuPgX3KXefziP1o61N61wlQ6trTA5yPW5K5vtEMDPfzzXfgnHuQpBBsWY6B4E@Zwt213C3KhTapzf/gnys@IwBPDEEgluxZO3zs9pZ3fGsy516PNkFZpeJEJDjALpWJ5petgMzUr9/0R@63oKVg3vRQa0k8EarVk9wA@cVTGOQQcQYnF42bh/WHYiRdK4QiAQDBNTDwBFVg71xzFbKwcam5AiMU5PnNOaI1QQyddK@hJOwA3WJk54TNgyoHgKE9kGSAE1wYX7J4Scr@NLh@QgPkPb9qrQZ/AC3sYnWo0DJpaLCZU2ZMimElar6aALZUV2tLCfFd4esqC05hZJ5LfI/jP7WB6PfgXKxGntiWF5hlKVwUcHZXKBCiOJCVGXVSihfAYPkjtm3RlBzHXD9VNTWEM1O0m9m8HgwCd4lHhcZC2V@S@H5Qwu9ZEcuBawwq1QgibMKL5a8XPgk5QQPgnki2MxnBBGeCxCAkVoZzBLBpuFg00qFCw42XRPsMoTklJCc8iDc93QNknURDFpPwTnDmD110E5x7pgM8HRejYIaNJQZnhmJo9MvcYstHKUUcc5lDnGB4CFUsZHPWvWVsddCSIeE1hIAZMQbANr8kKaStCzwdDX4CmQUJ6Uvo/iXYAMuK4DBSASX@TaUsYDJqA0MCr8cp3oAyq4cr0myTv26@EvxW074lv6t37RMLfrUFy39aUDB7x/Fso6UDRXQkPahpzIokLEl80ycrr2gc0TwPMOeC1pd89JlsRXKNtgn/YO5k82@20wOTJwRgke3BMd1K377AcdE2L2hOzbHbiZT4o0mm9huVfy8zWB3HReaJuHtZ0HXa7uW50THkKktt@vYnpXAA8K5ym7R/AS@SbcU1pOF0fUkSfRB8mYsguZ8hapuo4GHyTUaMZwappSCaac0UwzZMxqVsP0LplB4EE8C6NEw5jZfWq2xcjtM3ClZBDu1W@exo6FwjEIkewxkWAv0f3DtgQbDPHfecqQ9W1GVbo5jtBV8zx24XdD6Jp4mYegl8Idz2IiQORwSLglmYpO2FNovm0pJrJUwFRH0Kx8clH3FiJlKEN5YBLBAjAQbLdMYKTtaEV1jbXQ8mB/fyYfjexLG92QzvtQKX8aZN80r3PHDok7H5hDA4xyN9O1oYNJBbrVvoLOASmCNehUP8N4otmnGVRsx3QOve8K71gH@SARfHnwFiH@6jv6bM9APfvC@2WfiCZsnM5A3A5wIGKNN@j1/cDMG3g8VRYqsiC5g7QfvGRf4xfNRHqIKAWosCS4Ht5uEgjmEZrcXbILuA76F53Hi1A2@p9lUFe64AqfRRYKdG@uz6EGjbfXNmdWOCZ@JEFw/xcfQYCN59X4JR0FHQs/lbb0Y1F1K4ArVOBKdeyqtYRkzcaEo69mKe7ED7qGecsLwcD390P2GaMYuvgrvrYZ2QDSKW585FzZ2fw5nwxnf0bjPz1YQcpTXPzwncTn77QQBOogNXRLzaJVN4vM4FiTpPWqEwK@2mGTccNSHiHt53szDDyPR7SmFzA0Fqvi5LC3uzr86x@1NOR7iCp8n@bjR@7HkbUz33jwXYjUObC7C9j@sCrkBGedjtFqxMERuszHHXOeGTEA76qdz1tQqjRUCNQhJkm5sU3Ob9AtFwpbxIbyxw@lTeCPArjVucIby04Z9WuLQE0YuA3MY0lqEDSjpACVERU5ygUbIl@SbwfvVdRBna22crRtxthbiDErAYpQhT1JrIUqRC5g9m7Kgb3XGa6QzOmHbGV6bxDZcjmuOsLfiKmpHS3aCRS@iJRDIUStaOoiBUI62o6UHZPCipRMynEdLXwHDvGxF30RLfrFADyP4JMM9tBciHL9b0dJ@TLmWxua55fnxatFSkKfg5y7/JIoAKTDdoDXiEJvjimSORxZUbKRUJhhyjJfA5hP1wyToTsGfn7dB@/ajI/Zx7pBnFmf6QqURqjF4PFBt@PtCryjJJVGbHxw9pPlMgReMJg5tvHAYAg9qeCS6KIw4YuhKIxrwBgRRbpZWY8RCNdl7oiNiBw6lTF6Mn6inkT7QjpF7DTzX55HQISsivJ9fiyB4Br4fnhh4HZ430PGjI4xwTFZZgRYS9UV0Q6IwrxdxEbkfziHq6170hEfU@l54LhHYkEwHHY4G5zCyoTtcZBJyxbnwdjgMdcrxQoncuxSMpIIomWucyVqkDAVDuPArm5ITCoeoLYggdKyl6ryUBfUCyWJ0msu6kKbKCx@gEJI5UMKt1jkdYPNAGMkfFzcJqivWVUN@WB4lSa5FMQmBNdyXZ2KOeexB4/UAd@v5sOarH3KKfS0xBBAKGcTC5av7Afq7y/V3X6H2ibAUwSrFenVVelO93ljLLmHen0d7MwPRMcEeKCuVoyCGOcmhdRDSzDfx2g0VH6d8cCWfRxpAX9L2fbIFbYJb6LbctuCwUEsYXSxanhtgeW6sJ9RNjaR/oflKi4YxCTg84QGm86RtxpUnfFUWowv1b5v9D87g0WIGhzMP4VECRksk56V8NHFolsu8bIPY5jYoUvUS44KchkuDbJ5bgrinodtg2BYsjhrHD46ePPoaVLr5fF4RdfRsjh@WWuxrDepxDpkmRwf1wYpmi5HAMylwsBu74@k46K0zR74hS7iwBmXAhFh89hNlXBGyLCTPl8ouhON@QxQVsM7nxcBckEqo6phYZduCrmMgiDWO7ZgCiK/eAr0T1FpT6PSFRgOPAG40qPpqNHDyUqMhajHMGn9EXPlZZCs58UZ0BCE/OuRSkmhBPXtwxJ5/snfKTj85YA@f7X@Ffe3oGXu@9@QUF0Y/fXb/0eE@g/vgyckBkxamR@IxS9igBLo@sFoWno@Hm5plGEHed4czLndi@wq3PzEH7BO3ZeEw1a5nDu71@IfmWOMqD3UAzdEZ9mHadJTWwB7jfAs6BwqasajctGmtHc7lZ@C3CW3aAbZ5B27b7tjgV8K279C2PH/JF@vbkIMgb/11qwmuJOGRTzR1iA5nwxlYlxDcBP84dgNgTD7/ik5Ztj0ewGprTBAuuD6YgqcHx49PGC693z968uDw9PDoyQl7eHQMn0@/dvjkY6Dn4cnp8eH9Z@hEHh8fPTh8eLi/RxYcgZTGcPH7y4k33oiCht6JKq1zHPmmw7SDr8Veb9Tg2aVJqw49Fp04KH1ss2@/ttrRsjTxUH3BlY40VMBi23vHH38KdT6zXuEIpz8UTPMP5GceHT22nWK7FBsUliqUt7IorlDtqbpC4xGDGcOTCKwyrXOPkTnBfOA0iadtW0zexzkq2PfNl8NTWfZBQ0RbABtB@RNWKoxOEIlGE7sEsgqxtfoubmjIY@OTCMUHBr3nTzUpS0QxMVcGgeJ6hUMH@4P0cmABfA8Whoh2POIeWDqw4B5YhlugKnqIc0dYVviYjI8mKJ5Zjlu8HAwf0rAwywcW901qxRYETjzfKEtNFpzAhJsD9OmcGN7LQ@fXmV7LtimIR/7xDJV@nxcMi5/eBTKRDyXS3DbwKYOw6eBQg5j2xg@@RFfgBpwnZHbGHotVFI2d4uQgy7H5CT3dvunwKVDzqTvEe6yA279UxDRbOzjZhlaADF1iQDxVaxGPINwDoRVa7xsOQt6/EaMp5kjS6XL@FLTbELh/A4GfBwwAUhdaOi2qqWhxKYJxO4KVY54LHIn9tm/D/oGd25OWtRBAzNqKvbRfv1YEkRML7SR/niJhB1n02hqBWklDmR13BGWcxCqdBYJSsNVzh2Ob52FsMQU04kTVHPjGig1ie1GpLsSGdFiO0XGdUKRN4OI1sTaBKd8nVuJ4PnYeiK/5wZDA@VAJ83l3iI7ZxMOk52NnCRxEurSw@wUUYRorx87P2Zgw4fqnNJcdbxmeLVeoVB/cP1PfvkjgAXNcLPAzHf1Jh3gDY2JcUDxonI8mLI5Q7xIlzT8YyJs0MbSYgyekJZZyHxi0A3s2tOvuNcqBG59ufNMe18gs25PlmzcVHkpFySSO@fR6sbl0S7CaH2WCwtSZmAISkp2ALMj6mG@TIJiBvL6H62IwF8pAEQflCLbbl47dESLET11z0gHJIk4/FNkdwFdYlWZUzA@DxZUt4fxIfh67X4lXleR8QgkLkTPmi@iED1lXlNC0FKqvboB7sBkcyO/3B1fYiB2vHj4I2oON0D4INzW@HhavlkKw3h/s2w1geeX2c4GFtCfWA@aV5E1oAacHzJnYjgSzaTfH@OJG3lHZAzBY92IPSgA0FNvEoSFqf/vgGA@ghMHMFaKT0wcHx8dM5u0TCAtyD5sMbSEGEfYWezqfbWs7JOy0QGkKGsuB8uTbLMxo869NhXkl8daICqGDJAQ9AmExP/a4Y0@51BM1C6kQNPueBKJPuUXsrnwZ5NUE4GtoAwKy80wLJVBamcwIr3xsLzwJXNAtwXXj8Bx@mmHN6248U3A0CwMKzwkyu7iyZHX@Pef6ccmPhytY1qsJJbgNmjTUN9BOOIGIh@BR0xZzcEO2@FmKk@y5gh3xaYcTv1KLGvYvzlDESFwJ57pwSKwL5VigxvXjbV/NoQmJWA2YONNTOPIZzeDgi3iy2Q1nqDKv9GKLVRAomXjK3L0wV0Dw@nU5OPc8Nq8nK4FCHi5r24RNzceyjr2zAnZ5vaePcC50blk8LEcF0nZjVOo/TFS8lliIyaf5ysT4jgA5l82mb4O9nAo/uPqLwuZ1yLL8HA@G0L6fg/RmHnXvA@cePkn47nMG2EA6PrXeLzBLAUHVWVGnLKSdKqMwfoAL7xcCZHDbbjy4bzlWhU2XcFsNnddI/09xz7bVNrLlM/qKQibBAlm2SSAEY9IGTOI@XHIwJM0yxC1s2ei0sWnLgN2BWWfmYX5g5n0@YX7l/MN5mq84sy9VpZJsSHr1Q2etYElVtWvXrl23fSsTOmWZaoMxhHVDedRMUf/x@epwQv5mffO/vz4ebJgJTQcf0Sr/YDCMgtgrz4iiYnxC/9Xkt2A47FM29me6RihZcmN61tmOvO3Y4JVbhYmkbzNb0pHeSWx26ypZA1VC4kUP7@pE6V4pLd7LFUtmU/dq@1WxROH0OglZpD20HWPumQ/7zyFAczDJJXD5IB@@F9EG/AccXAUSyETefFmijfNN3IgisGtu0FUq0ixUzq3FdO93opbfx5Aerv0iErb7EgqSFLZ6tOfMkqwXSonygFx0089CKdfOeTYVhW8o0EVISRDcm/jdWLDQU0NZSj5zw7qfL64X1t5a1Lq@O3KvG28v3KVW2Raw@Pr96@h2eN/@pTu4uuuInrj52@W4NfntVyFWX4tXUNfKSw6lWlwr5ykO5Rv4uy7eFohzJYLvKCzsuS2Ex7e6CbEo4nN4aV7wjWZ0aN5AD4kUl4qla8WF6GI3Kl831i7K/XKhdN3oX5TQyW@0XB4tF5ez@OElrKIwx7BmvjG6wDXVlLoG/TuBl33SpWzSNUSQawh8OfCH4WC/cvg@IY3DDQCKwKStNwnU@Z7OObRmQ98Trx/cZ6WYzBXIsRZukKw58goqok87yZNRHNMOATPoFRd2s9GY/k4ca67g3d6MBpSiwu4ha4mH8MGaU25MBZIoQJZGeKHQ2SQ4cZ4sKob464StqHNF3q4V0XfSMUA0sCRNh/a5baNPISIqfbkaF1bkBX7rCpHAi2kfqJjY3KRraoHVIo@keGjK4Q/JYaJwgY@oAIGfG9I2YBW0c4/I7cOC5uN7ER/4C8moRuQnQwbyFu0UMQXNv8VX8m@i8ptAACb8HO@5PCnilDsv2Eiy7yAJFzACWfLgj2oGdKvkTpnDxiJsrq8cAydLcaIRVivJBN/n7pGcTCv4J1uQK9LbVDN0foezE0lITy3fIqQldSklbeFPLy6WNYrlVDGV2SDF3DepgZIuOB4dBDCsJmIn6PUAaabFXEwOfCT/Xln/sq4/amCdFxp5Ts9NpecS6R6nM1JxLg8W@DjThpnJznyN8z0KO87mTtVVFrR58aCnWx5sSeK8pefyRt5o0AzjzFu6K5krdcJmIiFnpHyZ0fucMp8ooxlcpzc4XfL3iux5jWUi7w/J@vHXkh0UkPGstDVJcanXD3vveNHSKchmNlBTCC6O/U1sx4NS@mDK6QR2cCjnp2G7VY6hLBfVjENjxt7a/MH25CbjXTaNBnsxTg2sGWPEoBLVuUyEG5PDItRDyfMGCIKJjCbUyN1ShSey8MQAi7nmVbXsBTk1wKFp6SFeRr/IB/yjBnsSOZUvMztxjjEfc@PZuzlJIJp05@3ZZErOJuguwh9lo55ZReK6J2mIsyeJQ0MKrOsM2Ae7g2LweT1PmBOFmimm6K5TJKXjDEXFvk91ISY@Wv/KL1nvfdhj3/SCsajgMcMnLywr4eA@CqJRhLGdKBZNdHtz00OtI2347smFWgYKWVlFdUsM0VjZPauGlj2c38Un6ZAOhTxxhJDv0UAkTohuu110JkMP2ME9Tq0ocQlHnlXpT1igAWPm1Qq7mQfiNmKtKZz2uyYS3HM8epDS0Y3fCjwL9mgR7H4sbmqHx7eUp6PfCEYPgyVtw7L@ehu2ftl5j/rcN8XCq6JBsjupDi54r17HDlZAJJWwUoBt7GrxtWUZuuEW64ZzCNAV@7jQfwLeDO6Cfj@wKrBiUMYINq1RMLwL2p5lHQdaCYxwkZVRM4l@2IPbYYuFO7Dp8oEZ0Us4clkdBhyGv7g@s7q4Rboy10KlVaxthq6@C9tIQOVx0hmgdpgUFhgmgOmBha6DERBlyRFJlEj3LHGhvcs1CqKAGhjnxNBNaDL0B6OwBT1DkiyrB6BYDRJX1m@nMIH6Wj0fnYO9WQige0xMAYWAUiU9h4Mllea/CwchG6Z07L7qmTzMfgMaKzDcg2EIs29MYOoVKmbgDh188qFWF/WjvZPPleOqgOePx0efarvVXbF9RjpuVJRTKFvx4WgfZhetTWet@RF8sCt1KGlTglU5PBPVnz4eV@t1cXQsagcf92sADcAfVw5PatW6K2qHO/unu6R9Bwji8OhE7NcOaieQ7eTIpVpVMSsuJ472xEH1eOcDvFa2a/u1kzOqca92coiVoVa/Ij5Wjk9qO6f7lWPx8fT441G9KrBh1m6tvrNfqR1Udz2oH@oU1U/VwxNR/1DZ30819OjzYfVYkJGA0crtKmBZ2YYjLNZE7dytHVd3TrBB8dMOEA8Q3HdF/WN1p4YP1Z@q0JzK8Zkrgdarfz2FTJAodisHlffQOCv7DapAv@ycHlcx/hFSon66XT@pnZyeVMX7o6NdonW9evyptlOtl4S1f1Qngp3Wq67A696oaoAB1IJ0eN4@rdeIbrXDE1gzTj@ivYMDnfwZCANYVqDoLhEYzSCwtUCko@MzhIp0oA5wxecPVfh@jDQlalWQCmhRsXNiZoMKgYgnZjPFYfX9fu199XCnislHCOZzrV51oMNqdcxQQ4OMM2AdqPSUWo39BHjxIzCrpTjXpe4UtT1R2f1UQ8xlbuCAek1yC5Ft54OkuYfRcA0hSjhAmYF/bQpWOtOf7gIMLjktkZkto9ERk3aOdquwIstgVXaccAqrznoqlJKZBiuNToTXRMiadnB5222G/c4AfUx1MRZ8XEddF@9NcfD6iHPrmesppHyFCmQyzeanShMOuvVm03G/p2QCjW@VkGLw53I5so0YDh9P3ij42dhgum8mCLX1Uio6yVAPFRCYk6n/kk3f/OvAEfl8O5DF0HkfASvRUcRqkytUpcDUSM6OeMdFXCVJJug9lOxABbMKvNdqopwULSMp0yCCP/2H@IUXB@MDzM4s7srn8RBLaIS/BaoaroRCItAfGZEg7FCVXhQEv3SzBbM6PPN73cGgnXUcVYbyjuAc2M063yh@GXRTxXPp8oQsqZ1l6PxInbtpC6P1z5JkQvaLN6SWZfFPc0Q/jsKGYz6g1JSqImG1FFpmX3JxtEhyhQxtge4V1Mm45zuo/FT7jKe5wsrrUur7B/2dxxbaC2IQWljwGlTugn4@XHAGGGAUiwNIEsoIGfm8UUbZm@jM95DxCjPdh220/IG1@iqgdR1IAhvZW79n1omr8TAcm9jDPPz@uHKwfbq3B1MnYvt6ffXNWsnSYbd@cvn3DOuhSLEUdewG1nHYp1GSMUp2YONDI8WIpR2zPzFwPo8ZMay66jT6iHEetN1G0pIJJzJsboQXvvTRRM8OkA62oAAc85bi15kjUzJANtFUB1tz7Y9pi@/DXol4QBqz9CbUa2P8g7D18FdDXDdIMpBkMYqdC5wLpwua9@w9ZSpKhxsK3INZPFvxMYdx0zQgURfZz6J3Lb1J3jZ6MWJTRhyv1O1UEpCYT2MhlF1Fn0f2R4ozIgXAFD0Mvvwk@Q0ez2SAOwp350ejyqgOZNzTJVFOHQujZaMbEvLFVhm66OVLXdOmQCm/I5GisSfFyTowiDEaCJULNCosixTgko4jkq6SLGB/WHTEV@ZUDN6BcEqSY@U7cO6s5kgoJRU/RL6rqBSCYekgJ0y1e12HpbKc6TgWipwJMv0hehD8P5EmM@BvwokToMfUMoIAfhclCSrTCo6vRJTwXikaDO1GTE3z01kM5tHsmCvdMKm9GbN/DZBA9s5EfTijsIed7AwCIJOjYMMcv9ok7cqHo9MPtiOLo56k37q@yQq5VqilYgpubu3CpW2Xq3Qr@OIIh2VNRoX7UFT8wAe3Sxr1cGRKHeXFi8hmcI6K/5FfIgGIHvDEpVdstZrmrIIcZWoekKGWjAWnrSMmwbb08Umt3ZIwQmQm5n6p@VKEAtBbiM90O@m@j4Fg89xkxEVaicUJRcHDeOB4TMbFR4asuyRDzF6AcF60SRiCV4KM7nGB6DF0CtUXQxPZF2QogpXEVodxnEGcbh0PSEvL6r3GniSTyKEa@9M@B6IPWKqlcngc4ENiaLrLe@LAnwDKve9rNrNYfqk@cNF2EStjsYQsj9eftAaDIWwdfWw34OiGE8cTn6XQIehHt0MZvxDWs3AoJRJq0w/V4LaJT@@0zHAMeEItCkfordD2iD@oSdcBWohyeJJxbk1kgXkVj24poWM4Xi6K7Gacsgk0obCkRMRNsSYeHjgXE1SGDA2IgmGkDxdks0n1oN5BD7/7wfAXXPtxC9RvB20dmdQASbJA7qRan2I8tkbcdHXvE3QFSkA0JYosSNOGqrBGv5HsJO2a7Dg6JsYupZb8/no0kyprKagoZlxZOzDfWg46E6m0IkOD6mChxZVVQmXWgevxycMYRQtNqq2Ffd7XU8oGbyLKL9TWEZ943tRPZ/gkhfzlFxGOHviCOm65BUWEcc@KetXpeY7wQ5uCz2EwbJsyUdjJtP0bFL/R0WfQJ15UokMZ9q/lj6JgAieAVj4c5wlGM/vj4Krf3Bn0/G44CH04p2EY9zHPePg4oUfssO5wcB/RzT6U0DYytSfxM8eX4TBs@K71kiUjNFc0Cm6yppnCaDipXHGYCJKcoxFgfHEj8fdNOkaaLvN6NS5kJf1PyR6v6JSeLPuqOKswa/QRgJzgtlIWFOxDOiLHJMP5tDSV4fK5DAaOlyInfOcJi70Exm@BRKSGSWCskJkySzAbgSezJzFutMdum2IQDjHQUrAb4JUzUZY@uz5ekQuzyDu0FNgQxfWCUZS1KGOMQ4gPk6fJvfLmT8YeEPgD6BdfzeKWWYxAU1xHRVuK@Lwio4wCLmQeGNIcTTMxzGJhF1ahXgJoc5yGmkyePEUNsvyBTZEMszfFlTgis3Dwwcvisk2YcpoTBxeVRbHoUNwO3IJURtnC0wwbfMt@lgY/KnFZcoYT046EnDWQfopULaAS3gaaMq81UeaYyt8eMSsr39trKQKWZ5mcGbfeZm21cyEPlJDXV1RrDYYwGdsp6klTj8VoNLhZ/E7qPTl3zIzMNovWLcf5piEwM1sZFsulNpG2PMHHSclK45NimiTFyNIMeAiPr/Ss2TxNxHG5ieOt3Jx8gw5P0Sy2m9KLiu7vNo99XBTv0KJXLTR6SBHuGKS0pL83mtDw5tMziITJx6smzRhNnDKaE340QKXIpKn0/RQi7pO4p@jRBsphvW2gndk/TxI1bSSnQp6qpESQS6QnBm5Hp02Yl246aHyBYeJ4h6snKb3hHLsTUuUVc5cYZBgTGCDuioNcLIdiCW7cWSk@otsBOtkmWgsVcSaCpy3TwkEH/dcEo6j8UrgjLR6ak1zxosSQxhoSnCoo13OQlL85vDaaY4IyRQoY4jNIoVs0NTddfX@r/mhbIB9A4NKULC19Cy42xhHLgA38MZOaY9wDx1XJkokRlRwITZoaYCzAKaXbC/i4iru/cMgcj9YNchjBAYI/Z/FnWZbAcN5rBU1tLDJuTzCLI8nNo80RuS0uEjMUvyP55VDkrS4dXAFAwBhD@XIRIGBYU8IelQIUesfkvASiso@gYLmIwxI@UlTU2M5zRjoSVWZ4vWrkKMzK8daEkZsJBDYWs/PEiMCeZXaWGAosdDNxMXK8md2eOAdsiBXvM8WhK2SvJGmoe44JCI@ErZ5RGkXhFiQHU@LrVSeRqPmbUt8WjNRCOhXoozFs5Irp1PVCIjVR7cpKsmiiJNDDMWtNJAIpHBNhPSv8sX/kmmKGPNc2ocYhI7HLkPbZfTxK3eO5zftbJDbJKVvtMRQ80zNcHb@afMVKIij78wHYxSKpDDB2@x9urbJMVZjIuwIoLp1ydsnygZB2rDYu9dgsPOmqSHs6QIE60w464tPJ3l4i7OvlRBkaXQfD1UKhgEx8aQa/V7bVKEoKB/lk7nznttfL39z/OPx0mae5PwjoSoANdYIOoEtgUETeYNjlmyEQB8iKuXPSkRXP@redjnkFA2oosfOg2zinjIYgaAEKtdHLpxMSABFIucD@jA3E9v0s9Oi793mjKaEoNRSURpPgO1tpz4A8@KGD9tlaU0XAcGJW1kywbjnlra@4guDNJtRZFL7Y@RqbJ9sfgl5v4IrPeDcwRgqYe0wX2NszCxQ4C2oYybv3NqJ4tK4I7sKe4VeMWUxeR3BqYVL3TKi48Bgb/zjoVsc3WbvxxYZlBZq8jM1cxvjUrrC7tiODxX8HWOZDQPu7cl/7N9kW0SmdGZZ6OYLjJ8DoVdGdefZJZHFIJiZp9u3cSNTZ6HoUrAGa7tBeQMWyp@6lljyRXRPXPh8XO0jDAsOQOGHMle8rga5mf960eDfqdL5vVqRrALhjf9eMyDeh/LEJkXQANALl8AN6YhTtv@RgWO@lAorwBgcv65ied7BAEwtY1otW@df7bKVSEQs3y8uiUtmGh1xOVLYrYhc/bG@LXXjfxveX5ZXV1RLPubvOV/i4rT4@im2AQRLO5dbVcBdeIa2MfmNorY1dvJAvL7ilhWZ5c6sU5RuVbXTrh6d//vt//vM//itfkS//gy/b9NL4ojN5npdfaH1dePlYwvfG7sXiwmVj4eZisVtCLvsXRQ0f1EY5PzYf9YaXVoZXAeMr2ZGqczZFn5FFhbrV79of/gKzy4bItKJ8Rn6N@OYommMzrcD4HqAf5SUc4dWlA@mjPCCRAaATFMdD77QCNMCD9QYoCbigHSiXZ92KEtxjOBidQWtVMjISD@1Z7wL0aYkjKaAvLqxYubAfBX2UgN/RnpebZ1k@/IajpuTf/JeDqLs9GIul86xYKoglVyzZNv0U197CV2chH6J3LmeD44Btu5ASqxbQzFBEIW306PxAd@2kyG1ZC3RlD0JSYSooM3vBufr0R84yfOFa1LXm8NJMwSISUjJhkczXhf4jdMtXyPFoJ1xtaKPQlKcYqszQqOj@xS2QH7EhQFzzNRNkYwBVoqaPPJLxKa@@yL626DYhAoxkPX6/R@MeP8BatNCXNs@JsxRec0Tm8/wV18YSO0MT2pjC9ccIkEKFj5MF8iRczCxabOVttJKayV7YZvsk87GtwyQYKdt0LvRvwmACtuY2CbfQl34t0pCb1SvCDrV6xajKTtt@C8socn3bG4U30l2BascB9VXX9sgjCXuUADEcjtm/MT3CSFCgIkWluoUvy5qI9gCbziOhL13ToYMdjzVHBhHyX7Iwth9SY9vJk5eIYgfmAUJKm/J1/LAXyagrQyJ21x9e4u2AfocuVBux3ozkeXhNagrjQUcj7RFkMjmPxzM0JXMz9LvXvisyh4OToT@pwbIFO59Ry3OghRiCCZHAwSerntU8hTC3SHYJUUQ3hSyH8PKC3kRej8Z9a2ufE@xSNRRk2BUcBAl2IkoGD4m@StEx5urf0QkmylOTt9ZGyimWZl60NJKQbNNthobZ1NCxVA3m2NEDx7YYVT0yFS/IQre40F6T4hdm8h7GCJB129ILULoirL3F@nF16gZ9P7E43fQs5eifLwleF3E801WUbI1kqZtPi/GNd4gV7CO/JKNA8NqkwhlZc9ns3Hkkr3PLmOsIBfnWtvh5X4T6Ajq6wIw8Q8RpP@TJMrVCxXdgeKJGlv8AodPzu4Df5N6fICueZ7Lv5vNO48t5/2Ipe95/OP/NIUzklKxW2ZzISGW2mrHkWIGVMe8mXpVVWqRCDZ73kxnO@4J9WAwSACL5bONL/uIhDwidZ/BO@fMMEyTRZYhJ/vn68gg@P4VmJolFPmPNOUuO6vzsu6IjYG2lX@xD/uDwL2ChDpUkpodzzrADoMhP99dbdjmJ8usrhdcrxddwEuoG49wwuMX1NhfdXgZj2EpEeJyFpef8twQ3JAjxOI78EnwcQzv5WhP2PYmkk5KcQuUwp3oszVZQxmOegPxAZQqXii4ujs7jo/IRD/yuAJZTeSkWFJsOGtyXxfUzGlxjPX6E81raO4Q5Eq0M2EaERKg5hKwuX3mKQx01XBbJz8kTOxi7lYBA9@YzxmrRH/RzcrPmeIsl3ESj10xvvbBeSI/RqSGaGKELcjO1OC@KW@/e/OO/j37NjDJbK/nPQ/gdZX7NrK1n@BEe4O2VervLbGU2MdvaY2aShzMwPL75x/9C@a0fAQ6mTDbhz9aqgrU2yWzlylTkIbO1Bg/FlRWo9//@/ndowwKf2PAu1oWmKwixkqLIjt8n3oV0UcNW8rF0MZ5WyDELYbCFIZzN4QUNo8Yr6wUS02WkVcVdICNfKXsUucSTYdaITIVYkqHsKWBnxAXKWEGOQSoTio4wbDeU2QYyb4ym@PmFtxbBCeBnac6hq9SmGy8iNBla4GMRdGCWa4TzPD9sFd7Z2rxjw1Y2JSW1hcSjnZxr11@V/h8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/jo9br)

IE6/IE7 code:

```html
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<style>
*{+color:fff}
a,b{-color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
b{color:000;-top:-90}
</style>
```

`* + body` works the same in IE6 and IE7 (IE6 doesn't support `+` combinator, IE7 supports it only in standards mode – with appropriate `doctype`).
`+prop:value` works as `prop:value` in IE6 and IE7 ([link](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-aff8d8f6c5ce6a560158ada7b9007854)).
`-prop:value` works as `prop:value` only in IE6 ([link](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-1a8dbf9f026f452604757340923e4e62)).
`-top:-90` is a golf of `-display:none`.

Answer (score 3):

## 308. HTML+JavaScript (IE4), 14376 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>              xxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa





























































































































































































































































































































<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:8][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:308
}</script>

<style>
*+body,text{display:none}*{+color:fff}
a,b{-color:000;position:absolute;top:0}
b{color:000;-top:-90}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/ad4ocod"r"n;z c;p>s'0}e}tfeqFloat67+?4disp[0][ ]
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgIFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKo9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vm9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrNGGrs/Y/dM28saaUlCXzuj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d1zcE8z5ljnbN9p2W2AxMbuqeXYb60RuGUYe2D13w3ejVnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeyZCR@dSeuUmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2HOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1TinMokuBsSfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@3jn6adX/Osp9qkJSA371vRK9LrOXtjWqH01hME@P3748Kptmn2mug57eB0lPcN2JmN3f3wVfpbtdC3HZIZW1Iyrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD20R5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILz@1xT4MAxy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@R1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mpNTt3R5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQmZ7YDUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@/Oe5QiUbKeL6Xgxt0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwiOhi1x7bR4Rzt0WvTIiytNoLam5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4ZyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@f4z5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@49fRBl1YCM2qgpBSStsAvGWMR3ZGdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttlHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2ZZwBS7dunKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SLiUoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3DCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9Kw3E6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKZzBPTIPbfmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDm3CR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOU@6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSXRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurYz1nPHSwmjYuX/SDpPRurgP65OYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrnn3Wdp3oOIByPoLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyRVCadJVQnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjtM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUwWoY93XNnsLjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@tYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyS5OBr0wI/jgXJ3n32dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qjO6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrNwUNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gNdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzlIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92LXrwcXYldvkV@lnA4JW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSbXkw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@dUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4gbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4EdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Qqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfzOSeJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMO6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9GriFH706a9vRqM6OFltprTzozR6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPARBczRzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vYvca7JBpBqdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abJ3ID1GTJ3uUmhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAW9JCQoog0UyKepPtCAlj7uROsMtJw51D7AY10AUdhGo6FABxAgZG3QOu2WPG0JLuXPH11c2KhVgNlCiQGy2lbBy7/ejaCCpwbNGSoiIRBu7R2MsGzEF0oueLzk2oC0Bp1aq7GLcG0GJo@9LCTwBWSUHOdknrMjnp/bppH01ox20RE8yljrQlezWWC5LUPnz0lBZR9XoAlVB@Y8iVZF5MTyBvsa8ZIsZKgtvI8tDrbciUAnlcAwxELy6lEQ8qLCbM/TurNUXKgE3QWHn0qgJ6J@KlnogiBJCJ/AL7bWSyoFgceBw2LOd40cVURa5Y7JpO6UFi77bMvtkvYneZT/s4/37hzuHX28sgdG3m6WrFkk7U8hhVTuZql1nksxoRmkzDGMO@EFjPWwMuOhHloQzU91pSFWataBymfrkPDj87CpJQBNCclAMYMb7ikrD/YDSJTVNr3elEmbdeByiDIL4fpm6z3yYgQFRR3fTx@fZ5O1bzLyrSA2FPWLWn5gcgG@Z3Hf8cBo6XlHAfKdmh9eIFBa0UNvB/s@5KezTx@dT1JqvIkOqdIhlPj14uHdYIbA90zu1@n2VvCS9MehS5qitAc/3J21LWuYHxB@YWiyuzRFHfZpwXUrgVmuBwPO8ZSvgAwBs4mguU/sDP2leD3DfvZo2slVbAQfQN0G4qleG9aHWxyIawgOruBa2dJfVouQwr6wCq6U1VuC6WG21slkrnymGq63WPM52GOiAlGLb9fXGETideiraaHMtUqjVAv2jx9cQ90iJhKaA6mPm9ZlGcXl9CVsvqs2iXnIXWmhu39JekMSTmawkk1G/41NredTmDPnfm9rjWErhb10BvxD7zs6@8cD3LDrqqAODGg3YBMeaadTBgYaWBzziuH2367ItCMO1Qz9CUJtWJnOn6zrXcshES0xqBEcuQP5if405hLrGfksNRwoVbq7yUQ/T8c5BSuu5NBKJKESgkuRfe22emUCuebqP9r@xB5WInk2lAnOKLiBBKAyRC02tkC1ZMBUi0gQ@SxMYjGJcK@2@gxoaRsBEC0EXBNyZOy@1JImpJZf6X4rSV91rFH/tzq6wFthw1gJDiGT7T5893n@692Tni5Oxkc0ufGdSxRwQDuJrgi6k9TjdsLRu8aKJyUJwESgbIyxeIAUm0EDxu8Mn3ggEt4ZeNI7ACq7h4z@xr7o9J@opVxNzjq7qa6fFWegJFj7uVQSEhna7j42RER82w/oc@ac3Hg@9UjIJpbw3aWrQaE2@brl9s5ukcFAx9PtJHZsu@wfYr@EtCwHIeDOLh@B9WqA6zKjj0OwPXGi80FAcigYW4@Cps6pvd3vQFsbxOmukaAEHU2qSbWghQFs5GaSNBDB9AW3F288nmbP2V3SjwPlaTxmZpOx7Wyj@4HejY0HTKQa1FZBCufLJTu6c3GEzkNII6SqQCNO2xJAN1gV9BookdZZiO98nDkkL7CZFWUE0ejPBTlyQUslsKpPXc9kkNMugmQY6q4pdberAHLd66thVAZ7qdqjfIMSFHa9lOh1tSxh8ZEHv@wSSmq69PDlx6qCgn9wh3HAgrDar1/S6UmbXg2wJ/0oZuHcheci7vgXwLhmBNenNVsiztnldnLVNKl1tlhwPhqLOUYfsyQ4oUm9dkNdtK1z2MEAy7JjcWvCbRM/vk0s6hPoYVMIHUioJBQpqWmC9JOKlgtKL6iFwDsitUAA2783g6eDDzyE5go1u5HvbjXrUV496DXaSekMgIvUxt1BKe9g/OIbaMeB8lNKQuSik2bkVxe5z0@OdlBBIDDr64aGtFkCgzvigI9oJBluBCSgUNc9BcgBfYW9pb97LiI1@4DSIkHDCzgfQIBwaNOiCnIHAPCE7PCE8JrJZTNKp4547CK1psYLatMe8j9@djHAwz26H0wbe0wb3A9AocSG5TqN@TavFe1l5YEoFNAJNNrAGLnYlgHZFosCiJJh8xBDbgh52VEOxSqk4cALwVXZvF6RYy@L9ReoAG1HAUnssOh4ld9RvJE31LXDzGt0KE78THsCmTD/2CUA9kcEINvWSiB5Q0k7cAXl6Qf0t6HjfV3el4WzcgxQDh8lmxR1aztU2H28RxpQyjbNGoyDwbSd2Ed3Y2IiWotVoAkx3wbSNprtoioPpLplUMqE/DU0UIkEmdK1RCLSrRy9rPuSpUkcemKLm8NYexsxaqZSuJ8yaLt4GvhXICqA8@FbxBXCiSqWCRkWRq@c4VAP6eyjtu8g7R62RPRQk@CooBPxb0CBNRIDmPWrzI6uMbdP1FBlURtBotFDFjI2iJ7XUSf3k4qQdP7mMJjC0UjYr0D4E4TWODbTuyJ0MQXGrZUoqyDalli7Vy81KNBXdisUKah8iMhXlk4ISNzmtY1ELeCp2chIFkgrq1Fq9EcGbJgxFCQgFeHRsaGX0@7GodlGA@JtKXYlHIawSTYBYrkSjQJcWEsGjRGOPAGeih/YUSAkFE6q48JgCCUgak8Li@g1r2JuNwh6CXjfQsrEHfT4YD4WBpHhYSr7l4cMK3UJL39d7uT9QbrHzDvWl4YxLd4ljepJcmBji17tnamfgjs3k5xo0mrRQdRndiCZVFWpCcuGQKNlPbA@LsOlY7sQL9zQu7QDF2MH2uDcBYenPmkkAV9lDyWr1XBbdvAfQWTDMg1UJjlipfNzLB9BuaXCjEEWtBAdLQLug6SQ2yEWcasJ7ZXRCgosev28@mxu@0YLYyhSGpTAiu@u4I0sFkkAIiSZ/0FQhqcrEjJJ96vm6Ni4hXKlKw4a3bYFEfNh3TaItF9eh8aDhIBQe2ucQ5NBqS32QHx0QjxrPi5HVTm5JNDjrjnpQQ0BqUBIbQW4NhEPS9YZtbTyFoFIMK9ywI2/dgdJ5ztqGYeRa2U7Jd0OuAGL3IJOwVepAE9d3UnVwVEQm7/FuIb@N/vTgwR7vO6HKFqtX7EdrDNz2BPRK0W46tJxugu0BP9mOO7CBDH74t6f9Q9cd81Y@fKzqmeGNZnsw6ZvU53O1W2ZtuJbbdPvUFbQu6Nz/ZOSZfZN3QvmuO58/AV3/@fFRRSuFPCXNs8HauLEfcnm0nJ774TFHGmb1h4c8zpjyZlbGesufjIZiRjjk0GEipqJBHvn2ebT3ixSOoQj7AtoPcBoa6MqiF4E@A0vhsUgecWoazugRlhd66hLtV7bBAn86@eOK4xzbC90g@7Nxp7NgnSbrUxVFU39unSFrPkVtoY0YRinLPeF8tQU/YUA58hNMW7vqTwivYIpBz@r7I4iHoJjgKBnU7X1Un6Btgpo4nztmgSI9xMEQktA4xMZaoGt617otoEwNVe5bimxQOYE6LImai7SZZKKLu0wlxXHF0KTHpacLTXvqPdmu8gFrbDqNeKstyTvfNxsAYrta9mcTrfKGMUWjgTeCSrhBCEomDdtfS2owCcOjPnWJgpQlLwmthqmRUk@m@b160iMidJh8cjL9JGV8AY0PnPO1eSfZtcoY3Upq0Tfvh271QGyw@HSRZJAPE6fj9tsqH/SC/Ge8uYQZIaYaBLPOSOCDjT3yJ5zZOIlFTAwEcRmaq3YN7pWsq173EJrdFgCC0nDB3p0mzt6xGtRgZ5o37NvjOrvUxm6jh4kfT0bO1XlwXKUcjcyZJ4mZKhW2c/jp57VUnUOQBiYOZBV4bk39aZSgB4Peg7NVwYTzbcb2mCp2mlhgY3p1DZCa0pgHoA8weARlFkQkUoSov7PezdPSsaDhGbMQc282SDBLudQ6fXM8thzOW3w0cTW5@bCPiKZC0d8VYwgllqKBFlA0bXQDFMvs6PjB3uGhBhzqxaJ7OCBTgmJntnqgb6xKtE/JcOJL7JN2lH2CYRRshUtQpKAx0RDhgXnLwNzQnIDYURR0rVEMLBUcS2mBNQ1fUUCucAkC4ayp1phoFACLWQqkiYCVluL/3OEtJ4FniUVZnCgJ5I7dKQFtbUWbOPYbzYN6g9RQ8BLlbU@aIlvZjJH42tQV4p@RPcCxYGgykRYIaajV2AZIN/Its8p79rKWUov1@Car18t8hB8Cok5PU27F9E1T0JMPh5GAFDjvi1ZZ58okXj8G6rnFUBw/HXhWEnwLyI4mzdn1UipvGrISIKu@BQvuKF9FcskkU46iP7WJRAjNhFqc0bQ4XyqUrOfUyL4yORyS4yMQpAeHIWM8lWyjwnRF8THjgF6YI2w6l9gz1/PsZp9mr3b6Np8JFlTWJUEYAcmnTDi6MhYMohuWZyhnmBnzKct8IrCgBLlTRQMtKUwZWcQUdoHEJFIaSEX27h1ayGzTYMQGMs4Y5vS99Nu0IB8fu4DsYzEDOqxzkNAQ01NQdJxIst94Wxz/RRfeMEieXdF51TM5HI7rnLZz6tIoUmBqpDQ9i3pmEHpw2r8esmN7PXoseA1w4H6NVdh5g2aHHks80GCKGKYnC@qmFxo2ZKeZPKQX9dgviXlxaspCtE2rM3G6NKaJZqa@ucGnWiyQ506zaa/yCkTA2Wb@e4k3kJVY8gwto@l@6cEOHqgWQX7yNtE86VdnNbEFukMlNYZQ4v1fvtkG@l/PnR7UV9ifGRgaoClgTqmdlZklguIHPZZnLO92n/RtkwhDpptAtswRJMnsB4bloGloX1VB3xjgQIXIceBNfIAuuobNOOZ8nNF/L49k2VCdA3K7tcrvlVlePCoaVILmYpuIwHUu26JAJGR5JlhTPrATarijwL0ZKX8qFiNm5vnem4wn/Anq8I2ZaA/xXlc2hc9U1mzqFjRIzaZtrcnykXk6abvq8LQbqMW5JX7nqaeRZRW0EjHI3EDj8uTzBI7sLlT3/nuVt3n9mjyn101c4TkTb6g2qW3f5l9UEAZrYhj1@XOVF1usVAoMq6lm9@lxS04U0IFRxByLJM5gVUNEs6@QuW82Z6gK9T6ey4L5CiBxKq14PJVeMWA9HK4Oj@1TCl8sLg891VqcHst6HpJ8lqzK@@YowWLe7A25CtWVPTD7qtEOGVcK82XTHa55DUZKKYx1huNEZ0tzbk59rJBak745mpvWsPgcD39wYlU/t6g2RFluuX3bwwLdXyU1/Tl387hwnjI9QvMq7GWUbENDFOtxNTAtlwJua4xzUVew1S1kGp8DijNtQ3yiuauI1XLP8V6pQfSgMcyfyyu1t0uxuoV8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@DVc9uz6LGcsKdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8ibM9u@967Iie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8b6tkAuElK7fIKR8Dch1dPFeKdpPk6PTmzKI1n@NcOJsyLimll0mqcSgzurUQdsARwSXp@xhqkAhtSTvQ1wRMY7lnJsz//0L1B6rSOvXHsMZadSg4GGAYgEM4xHXsn@R2DLrY2vfTihdA5u/KRGhzD3tW1Bf0fNaljIjpX9kCD2Vur2I6vQn1sRa2tY4aL62cBnxmnbG7ZFKiWRsiiEAHHXANS@Br7eicXgrrLGqxq@1wsSEVrt1szazKNSGoIAPsfX8DAzP0HA9RNeZDBdydaGB5hyuJ1lv6Bdpt72AHbp8rBwq3KAsLajonkX32kYTb@ThzLNKJpVKCR0mNJSz8LGuMZUOwr62@XMhYrKZxzz3i8N3o5BxeRxElvDcxpUiyFjVtifPxWLSsR1rPMPnLaVp03X7H5NTIFTbNmpjoFzSHN51OXZN3RGrU9i898LDPo9mZ1W/Ba9tRPMS6IPt5nWZHh5rulVuqjiaOsCRrsXP9T04oZGrm2LB5dzYLcRn9fZX65KiQ0TXClp@banjGqrbtPomf01zmXXwilp6LbxFoSFGgXHUmI8Vz8f4I1eE0nAGxLLb0FDpWQOLPtco@mb79cTzXys9TV28VzlPLauVnO5ZrVUehjbIBQefC4PTIWVp7DrQxBrjBEJsqvRxiqqwXSWB/eHEpUTeH5hdi@9RsU5SzvsscJoOb9nNjct7L0p8ak4Lgs17mFezBBSqU2vm@e@lAJ/MWpCvk8HNPW5XCn8Lu0FvUdpXzY29XsU6Pbfn9Kwen5AefK0qHMCPY76nyDrUAetuD@fIDYcLc@fD9Oy7/f5t6ImikQtK1@0sxWkPV9XikrCPgjszm@AgXjf235ljLjvQsLLU9KwJ1EueO3aHlkpfq7z2sa@HP1fJUH/0@xftRFrb1AeK@O9fFP6Nbcuu6Y6HQ3o1hv2JRw8KqtJi6Jv0pg6f80KzLd1RV3vrDpqasNTEhBgadF8uYpr2uNXDReics62u22z17JuQblrm2LFPk36vD/@8VdsVKWMz9QFaa30byDuaacgvlbD7Eb72V2W66EDi1VpgWKOvLOuko/Xe6tA8bXm8QxRNrIR9wqHSyFeFl2g5fenNxB7PgYYmSQU9vHxkAg2rcBfTMlZqVrT4Yi6GxXSNlVxKSjoq5KqVAoVHX9m/tDCBLlTE0mn@WIVQOJWEUWjCy8eQW0wqog5CO9R1C/YL/LUwG2ppJef0Jl3vusDkPfZtUNHwsbrbgiZJh3qtoc4yHfFaRWajn8TVk/BugM41sdYOq2TXjquQP72vmq4Nrwa8IOsmK/vQ@vbQ40@mdlaOxolJUtAWvzpkyGkzW96YFhnTtjp8FARNN6mIA5fGaUEHUVs4po@d6CjMueLFBZfjdkGoq3029@z7XaW2LJ1/tDz7gzpT/eKp1TVxEvdje4yzQJdwBbHssnlLN8L@2sT07K9NIGWrmA23guAjkaPwngH4tQTeE7Nrtx4tZESApCCwmELKXwvsj1bX8@K8Z3s4hyowrOmYQpbjTIxc14B2wxKfV7vug10w5gWIr69c6ntZ97o7nOEytBmZ1vWs22PqZRXvVU3HVbPL1iJxPhkMJ554LceBZmmFe6EHp2TvndsAXH0DopX1zP54eU91qMsVtDBRKc6Nq7Txb9h9t8u@UUgxUNpACUPlfAnj3Ifq@RlODRo5SziR4r7lyCd2dKgjnrA3kLdWmqm2Y4/X9@aMxzhNyH9jYnjNgUsfko/xqd37WAjq8XKKPL5Z15@veb6hfgfOO3Ino5aFxmAjk3CzQMRq7frTmnGpiIsbsZyHW2lrR2@gOnSdyVgdTZy1tUJuba1QYtNCLsQGLPa1vSfPlTA30DTwm7RQCxp/E68/m5tWzhm4wmS2A4rYajm66NtvSzzg@y4d0hzkG8Ls4OZQLRLXD9xl7Z1ns5E1vnWDCYT/ZPDAauHI4Y1xP3WfuI4LtdEQBOXg0OKbCSzM9VgeEIM9xuXyQJ/2jdEcEdgVlRDXNsyh1YT87c9Nt6mLOOAH5thcURVR3yC1/wLTjbxi95vW6DV1@oXMq5q0iwg9sqbUtljNMLwMquNWi6vE2B@3UEYWRmy8oes6/EnSNgUv/cl6qQJVAT1uP1au4Qz/hX6Bpe2zxaQenPGJIlab73axKq0jq@n2@XPNtCTH5tMCzJFtecnHuHkC2eUyTAXty1srQ/JrZci8aQSa7Jnp0Tj98qbGHKQ@/YhZQD1z1HJxJEwY1kzQCe14cIOYDhYN8LkDTSD8FCSW2ZqIvRdvQqs/aA7osbLBEMrNQ6uJy42atE3I2Jxez0zeMyT2SAhN6gp2FvDFFRbqHIs9g9aIcnO1tdCOWqSqPaQHSeqVw@U0X0d1bKv11sReM5foNe@bXnCHNCefknFFX3WoGFEvctKkJfRLS9Li7DVQaPqWOu6NoM2fHK/r3vb3b1kyHjIZWDjIvDgKs1J1db0eJdZdPp4eCNeRpYq9A0GWBPsIcv1Q3VmpeSJ4@B/c/2oSKuFGLuPvaQKi6@YRfEB@MnLE6zYc@Mz1xh17egB447qDVeIEk5WFIPDiJQNNW6sSAbnnTPq896Ebmno1aFNzTKX9a1W1T@J6bKmWc6bSDnPT6yly@Wqy5A5uhjq22qrYYAFHGtTH/sKywJt4LxlADctGnO@pJzlhp7mMmAG6jLjnvmQAfcsdq0OP3smh92z/8cGxNvT0pfXTTg/XY1zT4xZ2bDAKqVCX1GtzFBrv5DPS2rY3Tt4/0tXdx/saelhBbz6iocILR@YWXiv7PcXWo2bSXNkKQldrvFxBfHT85HF8vvaTxXZ7I3dgKWHn3aOjBK5t@erRUudw6IdQOjrudGXw/T1dV5aw73OHRgdXSc8lMa2CdGxBaxSY8RHf8OVG5arlDq328WxofQ6VJ0pw75bR51Ym8ql5ZnexFLLiSkJRQWVFLZdRQpOzobFtjYL3qvw8tYcoLVv0SvLXyukoqDmkk6P0cu1h3Yj/VS2GpcRMhI8LpKeuc@vYVqFkdHtoSpre3xcxXddX0fnI7EC@suzKzFr0sGx8uO@e3WIo2RKNFzWwUsfAVap941TyvDoA0Z3EB3bPC0swNldOg1kHILDOLS3w55YzMx2VxrLWqRclCI2T2tZ6@YZ1iwGpYIbPGW4IvXSML5hVz2ItMio3RHw8CgXZ3b2/f1OAQ0HL9b4@ffqcPTM93N1kvccwxtYtMJ5rRq9V7LfCrfVWDqe2RwDKWAuvO1xenkvsyBy1XWc2vXkQjha3YtVOmxUHsPCLPFl9e2ovq6tavF/r2fJpRjfFzddxuLMFPTi8640A9OE7/0zXUyna0wjfeop/3pAzfgFnMTSZM9woL@x0vB@IhhbqLRpYKEtbo4@tKU5H4b3Byxr1S@u33Jq6L6@srk7WuRXWuPH6g68VOpw44d1rvYTYf4Av8eOLrjzN32I4FnPicUVZ3MU@vMSML67CPc74uijw@@4d2xDLn8AhWBEmFl3hVkigi1m4VFEiELgWLuZUKnq2yO7iXvIlkLQKxQhWJb7jjB9ZjW1eiMVMpZJ@iQu65JLMxGKzYANJvgkiAMbt2yBRTD3V2eYYXDb9pVCMtvFm7xipb1Bf6NkUfGnJ8NrUslgjBjhtXjzbf7Z3dLxz/PyolqpfyopYCclxcxyIzV8j@0m6LUPiBd2ALfiWqLSWsg/R0RbjqPZ5froYpOxK0ioLSZsnSr6LYTYvHCeZpCWBSfUS8FNlHhu5goxHKw7bTzFlkFjRWeIr6fpEUnmTg5YpTsi0Eksti3hoeh4kS7hfPeSAXFk6ja48YrGLJRTGruu2RYyexW6@/Bgf7uw/fn64x3wE51xzbrfHvUoxyzc5RdGpWpBPHZtmF1RYVASJQl5VKtGHUSBMVIuyEi3EpA1GgdHBm08dXMIpQm@x2CbBBwpGg0xJ/pdvJi@jGk6UU8Bv1EcqygTl0QM7xsVVf/aTNt@A299SwT/JYzQgOUFL1yWxcHLFskmkKJXM4erzPGjDa1ohGey0PT8jRaL914Erz2k3pCs75Si0eQU/nEVsZORHRAzib9qLPS64KRE0F89sXB7JcejgHkGLrIyDtLQvlsZ28LAS4Hlm0ibwgPrEGfN9OMSq/QjwkRZIlATbJGT5lvFyyGN0ewNYuWl1bYd5Dqix1rjEXgOfYa9Gia/RVdVq9FoQHzQ/pUbtjQf9kMdrmwp5yZNx8sOvfTfZLTMwT1P34etXxFcHzL/KzS@TmNfXNx6axx9GAjcLE1jzyAOaI71D57I4fC30nFi4P5IvKpk9gKw5I0qjdx4Df6ogYedwYrXPIaOAxSCXxBpoHp81qsdwt7JSMolshCNEGs37tKZ8EsaVXcty2VxGTwKS6pkPkLYZ7uICMw5QUUrA@NKZPay8agJ7bW8zGbUiq5Ir89xMbjov0/KrANFN8Cud9xC5GoMwEGQeAtyqIhjUJ3FdwaAoj6J6FEVR24WKhtyxQsJvRxBCZjEgFqeRhfvWTvGAnvFo5u@@18RDb0Jb0G8KQKoO1QyZFFkSy3afumNgmYUFy3zZLk5C4pUabmvl8QOoaNM75EHtemmarzbz97oX5UvDcs9BpVNX68dw3sovEMQRgijJy1i29pKdjE@cepLzJgM2/ZFg2TAzO2D@J8nuCp7l6d65vuVZ7OqGZUgsdu/IcVH9ewiJYTEjaaSTek6ZJymTWZokkSIRDSQHN2J4B9GBaAIx0bLs1@7Q29nd2//qwbOja9t6kc/oVW8gyavb8RNVS9TqgSEaTtZiltx/mDx6cv@hnxFzpHMhCQzqi0iJvi4l81YdgpzPEr6atGUYXk3daoxf8KWEV/FNG@tQo0DX8NBTHxEvzdRTH9J8@6uRG4Vl1Mpm16E0h5cMgd7li6WuoRpTLi5r9e3qiROJXueEJQXhZUTbwkIAphNvazOJzH49cZiw4KC4YzzixguXxfTysihvpnF3GVyuOXZP5/vqCIuQQyi9fjQgIiUt6XtdWfoOuNo93/3J4AfZ8X1owrtvhBDOpdZRPATq2D8TD6XIfO86sW1bD9pWfbsp@bue8O3b/F2mgp3b@I4lMUUSO6DziGPilLxpaarRsHxMQWlHsBJs3U5wPjxFggKN@tqzCbTxnrlDviMuDb88sHzToQvi98GEj@Na7KuTAfjr0OvQoq4wkNwqBAZKRgNUuf4EUkJsBDeN41Z7EF8Nt4MTCdcG7Wxsqmg9a9q2uyDbY0oCJNonul5nwWZxmGjaHM6JypRn81xYWxQ/xSVwYbJ/1I6B0zkCZs3UbKdtTWPR86hSqkP8aB89f3EWVeRlvEQ7F4qt/NpXtzAM0M/r6yWJORal098fcJm0KBavSwmwuwqY773jH8dRLGo9T6JTlSqoix@NR4/BCGpErDMwhyw2cfj@RBqjz9hJzEnQhi5qlW9x5rB4nJpI8CIHjVHIDpl4/R0znRmLJSvABGjrOW18vbWHrKZrWh3MFInCNvGYnF3QuHCvD0WCZi0EKRHYCrIQNBwAI15INM7gEAbdJdyCZUS7PC1xplNDqMfARZpQqln1DguddrSoOcrFYklk6KJULDLgvuviUEsC2GtyztflgbpiLwGgGTRoNSkyF@TXJV6E4o1wRB6JTQgAnUhoW0J/bwIGsOabBrZ6I7xjew6UFdxOpfT8@GGjoCRlFmxm0B3ZbezR4jvrBo02cRYCFNPkgtdombfRPsVguEtVg@@WgJsoPaQCI18RqZEwGa6e/TnnTV1fy/UioMgF8JnBCkCs@Gj44HA7Nn9scYnbcmH/85/j6aJybPNuLt3on8Wj2VQZHno5y7Lsk80TVd2sGdlU5d5m3TTHJzIzk5mtB2dWr9Pc7yZPZJmlWSaZ3DJyb06Hem7rZU17M63LtUIlcVp/dsqePfvifeO9Ik/PZvJJjOUjbPfgnaxDAiKlPCsyvJdedOzf0mtNK12OAtyTEzw1VM7LyWQtWoc/Ob2Ci3uqVbWqdrf@/r1Sy0OaprOTCB7Gxw7uLQKLGYZyZNt2kp0MvXYbbrfH6vw42Qi/4vGYyoSFWuN2bDDtkN10x@p2J3vmjNvbkQm@Ho5F2CffePHiBRpe0MXeHorwHDrz4yg1zGyEGSnjz366cZm4eNbY/rNvDZLWBr4O8PXdyydoPtKzn2xsfHL/fiaTACpx87NvPPv6zs5O5kEi@6yWvZtRUxvbf/onGxuGsW0kN@qep9ejtdPTL2QjlZG1P/txtPHs2dc8D7MFrzTTwYjPAtw66lSn7C1cpx2GfzK/bYfMJpqbnbfMiLyNAFtHZvRrRBgvhRXSksLXBtOrd/P/9fsHbyLjSNVIvhjBexx5E8kVItwIBvhK@19nkWpkG73lLiOzZKVSAWP@v/47CF/9KsBBl9k2PKpZH1ZuFqmqFQryLlLNgUE3DIj3//rmN2/o9rnHanDJmbwh363DtUXXtoRbSKmpZPKKd71wR7/DmDPujS0XXzZ/OfBiZtmBVvdhLR6P1zUVLq1BgZK6bpxQh02Ytai/JRJYlxm3YSG7OZ8IG3B7ESGeAqYivuJmYUGsxi1eXPX3YslVfvEPfR1KkdzGPetBtQqi0KgaW9U4XRsnpRInf5LlC7Lr3sMereiJHGWv2GNB7KqcKhhyIpG418CzmtkUaapOI3MCMk4jFlmgbITNv1jYKsL8YGzu52P97eH15//bn//gz79Pvx/Q/R9xty2nbXeSWxz5syq/WLUqV0fyxQl93GOpUqFUSDbY5Ulsq1atHzI99em7aDYdPcI0kid2ovg9nJHgqlbx4aOBX9UIt6ly09xOuFSDD/IxD7LcHxOSySdqBKpgMSlJrZ3VOW4cv/A1xYvV7kE2yUa@KNerRtY4gKzTZcq4IuttesyNiBTdhWsDfvSH6y52HgsbfG6QJXchr0uujQCVm68FXKVIrZasW3VQZFnVB3Jvo7RRKOVKBmTKasDlVaAjZ2FpouW1gmaA@Hhf22CHnNfrLO5fJ/Ebr@ea1hBGMrh4q6o7jUiRf4CrKrHIBVz191u198C6IuqaKKfxbbVejQuM4KU17tXj6uVlTXsZL5fFf7saGMt0cRMkpH6pqtsvAVbtOlQOlJ5a4@U2gI1v17Yr7i7dWgNJrNZfVmvbi2FF8Hv34ihj7wGA6madRTNuNOfeY0o8vqmqG7WVaQDA9RiDVgFk4OX2ZfWytn15ub0N/216Xoo32F5uX/vTa36t8DN3p2JzUktWT5Ingm3q8K0lq2ijJU/AUIU3@INqSIqoUKCkyBbbigyZnk@DiVklfctIJ7PTT3J7oBrV6iq2YCpqTc9l6yqXVK80VlL5Ft16IadoKIoabqeBq@o09kqKvPrw5f@C98mHL38f630olkUpktzC5kGRtxLg8cRhT548wfuJ48Af7if8ctAGLZ6gncMfDvfh@wmsuQ0WBxAKTDYKObkR12cGi2zLuTyKhV@6dkWj0X/0yijmo7wFjavPXnlg@UvLrn/0S6suKfKuiOW85TGeJilC5R7yAspPFY0X@Gi@wd/jt/h7M8bfcQt/h2/wx47f4u9wjL8nTfw98/B3/AZ/O038HQ/wd/8N/p6M8fe8iz8pUgFle/Nuqp9qpfRT/RQMNkuNWKqX6ultbAmkLJaapWYsNXD1Npgs@KXAZKc6LNVlKSfl6Do4gmHMUmM0deDVhV8HoIzgZ@P486meajGIpQ9A@Sk79H4Hgkw5kWrQhJRfWaAWa7qW0nJ2Hfcmr8l1o1hgGlJYa9RenUTruOmlUcyw5szaOHnFIh6o1OVI8uQkyTsHmJEp4zbml5eNxt7TB41GEkXRyRP3YP4/OBiEP9f@BwfukwN34ML/4ODgCbOq8Xtx9R5clWp8W7zuRqrluyclFcutLyoiye27J9W0iuZcHEq/gXbxj7zmEOFd3TiRogw0lfMy6UPl87PyeZkMwScYGuXAg/DGDWBZFnoU2JR9heocrrNzssQHGs9fnAQmbki@OD/BdgE0@II/KJzhz/8Gf/v/Xf8nz1msVgf9JnZxuR2jS8GfolxcXlyKZ1WJxcRHbBt@aAHfGOTisopG8nQBplpMqSuXl9wOnjFlmwOsYhzbVQo89wiFPxLESfHyR@y/7RvjFtcJbo9tzkfqT06mqZRSbvrb8eIolfmOBkyVMh2ustms6fU//TFtunxXIU/ZTLmsbzH@YWSMcjnjf@UL5XLB/9iMxYrXr2rqrp4DBSeTUZRyGT7u@mBT8BmALQBY/yMLUC3PbFG5L0cu9g9oO2IQE9mIginigiGWol3L8QCMqFyS79yJiYM17@4od@4YxdS7d4HNcAhW@oJVo9G2R40G2qffvZMbMo2cF7PwnSq8eweyLKq4o9hTPDcFIoqpOvvEqFKcRXcEhMiDM9OTxhyLnumZ4/Eo9tYeJmScSePJCh1rkEq5o5Poz773rW@dRCsVWZXJNqMjAIyFZbe3c5lqNZcBc64AlJI3L/gJH914UVcuN5MypwaTN6MR4aQX8gqXjVF0hxqO3a1CAffwYheXEcp2lskqMZCuCihalxH8cWu9WOT2LJOLFeJF8atsKKwKOgD/Yfs0Hc9s5bfu1Rn9pssuFMnlC6uiX1YurBJ2812WW@LQOlx6Z925ky4CTQup8onUaDzYOd5pNCqyLGN1CA@0JOEu4Vk5w1G0RhmeLdZrmL76STRaKt8j5tALWRaJloU/NQq1BCsUiQyS3cF1tZB2SReN/w3JoDc@JNEXtAGWeK48m9/PHu/s7h0njG1QaYyHO7sJ4@j5/YiOn9n5Nzmn8ftwb@fBwXMI8Ozx3s7R3qf7n@89fwb2HjufX74EFs/5O2xa8n3OXkivR29NyzKtiWU1zieT8zfstW03bCBsf2LbttsdMc9qWJY1BG/@VYa7ZXvm69fmaEgX@/Cj73z40X/34Xe@9@F3vvPhd37wsy9/8B24fwL39/j7e/@2mMXnz778Z7/74bd/Byz/I9x/BPdPf/blb36T3/T9x3D/55DdH4s75I/fEsD6lZ99@f0f/@zLX/0h3P9S3D@8fv/aT5ffP/j26hvDff931/v53r@D@/c4LN/v936b2@H7mv/f5v5@9YcffuPf8/@fih8af@fDb/wxPsTHP/3hn/7nD9/6D4ZR@NN/8@Hb3//w7W99@PZ3P3z7HxsffvPf6Knw43c//OAP/uoPf@@v/vB/ov9P6Pl7t/l/@OE//Yv/9S/@97/4Q3H/FO5/D6af/sV/AIb92z/4Ef6//wd/@0c/wv///K/@9g9@/W9/5V@T4be44f/@l/@WP//61/7T3/yL7/7VT7/5N7/@07/5rT/4q//jV//P3/xPf/3f//5f/4/fQsvf@ulf/dGv/OW3vvOX3/7nf/mtL1c8v7P2@eUt7L/8B7C5PZ63gXObdH2szZe/ED5/H2rMYwE@Ae7@Jx9@85eBwX@DsQ/f@QlOIIV7xf8nhk5@fsK//j9gMK6nGV1SYIL71z9853tIov8BSAT/gF7fDT4WXPjHd@cfQNZ/cSVQxCotVp4FoxDfghbGVrEoKtDAeZtC/uzLf/7jIIpfXoS64AYxfhcl1YLbd1HGffjRNz/8@B9/@NFvffjRr2BtpmaKiZ2Eqq/vfIYqUM3ewh96zN3GH3j84guIfxqnrlI1jl/sC@H4xRdfSNN3SZyxfO8d2H5BVvxi3AncmHDy3YQ9zlQN@@HGlG/cROt34aiRDHGMNk6qwJavp2TTbBr3Ow@xJ453IqKn6RbvT8Qn2aLzVMLH/D83TiUWRz/8wkNefCMZRDgRBTdKWYgmPp2Gei9J/SAMuQ2NIlG8mSLDFEyn8Sm0SMEAMcTB6X6cVSqVOAascHzgk6NWLTBCJR6vQLoxNA@TaBQQxPQ@QYGQlfgha2xVpjxgHOFVfXLEJbQ6lHVDjhcqDyDCyvQBQ1gInMC@elWpFirTKoJ7z@kRn8bvE04IrBKfVt/Dd4VgxrFT6cF7QKVQicerBYwQE8mzJ9HgmZSlxFHa4ywu8gDe1EN7j7FPZL0g8xGNDSQY943P@Nz3XRpjuwvuJ/EtkRz6@0a6t4jgGxSViIVx97ukKt7l2iN6ALiqqmkag1tVEZt74DzloOIULbziHEKcOII4ILAANsS8iFP@xukD4o9Utj76ilclnprNzU0pUpXT8gGN8MSh1T46LfFTOt7xplGJybmijNYWzfzmqbM2n1G3w9aDLXjq8N/boAnZcVYmtDaj2LkXZTw@9kmc3/fubbFPIPX0nttJTI2n3Qx2rmNCt@Nx2YBYq25cegnSTQL2JUDvJG1aoXGluJRIMKZVIujGDg4OBGpk8bIixYH7jbSO3zgQMJlMIhBC0xJaIiHeGr3JQhMGjVzFW9tEmlNnJDOMTBnaN2WGVizcHNGh3YqW79@/h8yiSRmlfWhRMjE/w8gUyBEs@ELOfn/mLxwwMkWJN6eZnuPnaMfomD2FKRKLsS1F4tN3ORLBcG/UKBSiaFIgT7TYlj9dJ6dLfh8hdREGIXgbr5BVfMfdA7Z78OTJ3tPjYb3OJIvOP7Qaw5HbsjxvnWCOYbidpw/47H6jmEM0IrUaxnxcMlAsSXulFAnN/QeH@0clxmkicigWQFLK1P8rSFHUpchw@GI7IqY0yHgghysf4bM0T3/MKKYxwmpZirQsbJYAw@GflaUnXve@O4W2fEKWE3oOm2gK9aAy6etuqVR5r2fyErzpe8Jw6yi@zhRKJ84B17a3iWhS9UKlXm80QgbnpGpVzA1iulQ92juGAMcHTDdSGoOW/kUmb2SymayRzuWyeUPP5IqZXLaQhroml8oahl7MZIqFYv5Sqn7BphriqoK5X@lbTnfc28QZOfJJSg7RY7OWSuDPSKfhCRATejZf39joX6iI4AmxxQVOrbqEzwsVKfAVuJj0FYl9BazggjhwvhQTk9X2D8pixhDu6BDj04ZkPQuFW5FOgJE4OGkYvspDKD7Q2A/dUmTjG98Ys2oVGtnq/kMpAlKqx/xZM6rd1noa8VF7MrLItctY2/7cxmNatLbtDfvmDMpmSpMil5eXHYC0/xCHVOmTh2jj87JFNk0wX05N6f@//h7X9rAK7LidHFalbROMme2kCcYmGLPbySbUB9I23/eI4bLKijy2prjNGreTq57V72i4EKAiEyhD3hb7CFZFuCquqHDNdgXX3uFM@JhyIbUrbbdFZ0BJba3ptmeaN571ccZ83x1VoqB2RX0HG4/VxAVYlRqra0N3CJWjkc3Ha3oKZDHeeiFhJLKJNs63H5pjXE9xN5sqndtO2z3Xvnjy@NF4PDy0aCb@3UyxVKjXarIcrxG0Op4cx8uburEBPGqZbRXeHdcZe6pRqJfSqYJ0GaQKSEaoVqWtOOKXQIJcCO4tOa5jXW5dxCkdpU6ncymZieaFyr8hWeWh69EmxiWzCVUFyNby2B2WUpdS82LuSUU7tQi2JbMDdcNFi0@iK8lGtiCXa@X5dz4nl@uX0r2B1bZNnFF/krq4FiiXki8DPycp9LbEUw49QUJ58oAf@A5PVZr6VQNhVd@DOqhW3/b3fkLuMAzVSKtpXdXT@L/BYOD/9v4N@Bv4hFBpQzrG9Y9PQWaBUHbYY9xqeuyyY9elU8XuW60VPnZ7Js1x2x25nvf38HPfdE650wObbzoUOD0y8TgBb2CPeyt8PB8OcOmkNfoHg7A3aAKCVKjIw314jPquu8xDnj1/tiKVT4Jt/oAYfJ8/8H64/@mj49D7eG9n95GUY/cPnj648soKT1n2eO/hcfCZ565@0GwA4ut7jx9f/RSvCFbf2A27wbJ536BLOEn2DjRe7ghjNjc3ptD4gq/fsr1g0iZfqFeSjv1FXSbDEt20WIuvZsXWFO00IZQqPV@UpCFz3HOWT7G22@@beKJiZwMseyYuVrFQTejTwZ8Y9bk76rfP7ba1IT3BdTFFHY@NQySkRwBkMGnRsm57LOG@RW086xC7/Zt4XPsEzxNdYQkvtELjyO72QBCfu74HqWmaDO6PvSC8Fb7G6y3GPA6yu@bSv@5dikioDZpjM1Io37mjPxsBZ1cLqVKpa0F7AWRgdW8K3MUm7DnwuzlCSbqZZJtZOdeSHzKtETG3QAPr2jWvPjxkBeyLbpnpzBbowzrqFKAEmlY@gsIXVCCWKDBUh1BVrRmgDp2kkmY744LiIo9kp/yWtcrDqhdNXVqX4471hna7yuXjdzMouKEGgKpFYuXSX/@LnyC3byVBsEV0WcaJvRu6pJEiahQL2UIxbRQShWIhk9Vz2WxCNxKg5@eLEHdKL@i5QraoJwqZYjoDmh24Zot5KcJnTSW3CCS8SwDWaeGZaNuky2q9qhThI0bsbcxUWMQMvidMtiCMjKdge2NaObhlV2Qjw/QUg2YMQDRZi0UePtxNPXwoy/fxA8fJd1Oy3MaPbCGVyt@XZYtcdgtYR8suD1PArSXkMf9Ipe7vyvKEA8BdGWW5hx97OewFkWUbP3Z3Hj7EeDr4YWB48HbKXfhH3//IgzcHP9Jp6kaR5TcBOPC3wyPKEKZ7@IFxostD7rILbrL8qY9PKgUQDrk/DuGRn9adHVne5x87O@iySwnPclQ/w48dumQZ2AhLkix3wdAdQRmW5SYYsTzJcgtMrZkJdngCHW7d54xNWZ5xAiGJZHlKvs3WqSw3fHuM5tGjR2Zv3La6/JqN@LsFqIGLPZ3sPWx@@mmz222OZjt7nx6iy@7uI7Mzm4ya3aYI1mzA5UIYcDkdzK5egON@o2H2l7p8Bi7OFZfGrGEhbg3zDeAkri5GMmjsgssuuCwbbOPQ4BqA1yZe9wfwvm82ycW/yIXe02ZTLiOjoppIx8hCmaETXRMDszVyy/g9rWwwFo1FE7NaLlUvkwMbgEKYKl/S@bExfJrY7FYuZrVpJVWvTCt5g8/S6MTkk6mRteXExuCuXsyWNsy7upGJT0u4ftjtRFlU1e@ymH5n6y2LPVXuGulMST65e1eVa3r9rqEXSrn8y62JLCslfN5N50vgMRWFRik@lFq@fjefDQXJ5@Nm0ijl80r5Esgxhvq2iTKmEYudW@apoiC62HiCJPDTa2eUTrvciU0T0wrHi82U8rSil/muUix1DVYbtzCctMbuiEPsArjp3VSJzseV9WJBhviTyZiigGQiIQLv@RysF187Pj0@/gJkFjRLRaPuGT90sSw@P320q0E7T3zh1oPaQ1TH3ZG2i4JlwYXvjOdbHYOI1R5BpQkau2@HazpGbl/bm0JTG7VZ38HfUEoT2wBpx48W4BxBi5bHjEtiy7SXhNOyGO7MaLeZWamCyWyzGGHFTOWcqutGtVppVAb8iNtqEOozRoJ8Dmbf47gHC3Up@AWucxAOjUrqstysTCNTgNOoMFV/NXDbr4x4q9zGDRnvV@5j4HID3s2yVbHwoF85Ipc7d50KYxPHMzvWM2uEy873DzahUsLFD7EOs5RNdkLHAu@idn2pVkfMmWP2dDKImWq1qSxahT6RNLGv@Um@oNU4OHx9We5UWOylUn4Dn6NNFmtr95W7mXI7dp81FLBJveq86jCD5TJlOikthpCgEBFt6LhdpVL9DPQdDvi0VAJERB6fAkyMCcDabXIwlaF9WW5V@iymsilTiDyZcrdSw9Dv8LGtynJdVWvv6lJVVV9IVSin5VnErHiTJu3iy1JN3UjlylOw0/OZcg8y1nw5LY8qQ2j6l/vwKXo4@KIjswzkBKoBmLfvYh9@@ZvKtpqtcLsygXrXBxWjoTUq07KD@4IAS1TSFXCI1zKpRLYAlX82n4AK2QBtIJdIJzIJNY@2UBtD0xAsddAKYv2YzJicSE1Tmp7QLT0Bpf@V3X7FlMRpDLQTIhl8jN09PGUYbCCTkCvpE94mU@LGVp9BLrjM3FaJTUFSlDFhQPMeG9qJHoI6tMw@hVAUlaW3Yv3NGPrZPJ4M92r1UmlvOvwaOMXUN3dz8Xwq/lZRyrENpeJZb6RqWaqiVKFUDzeAZ0XnD/Mmgxrk8XhTzxulWq2JKcynEulUGpJnN951t@WqXE@kNnI65NAlIz2GcYHBdZm5NjK3a6COjUd2M71olCWN5jlQjHrMKK5araJIOMNOAJSGQtghhVnsRPaX3cWi0bwRjSrRMnYTb8iidw8kHD/9G0Rt9I5@Vwb9SS7JRQM9zAUlraxKhVWoSwlVNpYpSpEL6fLichsaoUma8AZKI9sgk6pV70mREmOgx52IvTuSG4x97Dy6@Hb1JX@f4ExbgCvRvl6gLdLsFsvGlhP7HFeR3mVRQMwcDWqGka7XjDzUbyAzfa@GoZexEzyCU3q1KlDeuwD8tuNVXIDxGZvNzLjqU/YOY934pkSJjlwl@05lp3u4U/a/drEf7kSSZbkclSMX0Uj0En5S5B6t@jD4qg8WCa374DNFWxbQ532EJAbbvfA7Z0p4ukTMLHH5UKsr75/a/YtCWuW9ACCwLi8jm0nKETF5vvzZKyMLeeS4/mx6aA2hYg5VVzaLnYiR5Kuh9w2jkH6yf@A8GD20GJ9MX8g05GqEpXQV56aXS8I2yyfTysWCIRuniQi7FylH2Kka1Us04Z4Nj4ov8y8LL588P3h@8FCKnGy823Cxg5n5ZGHvna9@DTxG05koYyeVyLSSKYsJTdWqqm8buC1OnuER7h09p6beVTn7VskhZ4DLh1/@YWa6XYBvA7TXEmRhNm5Uq/qWwZTI8MOXv4/bIVzsfb7zmEU9c8b@7k9@bOT/7k/@FU0Til6WPerNzEfAJxr1XD5ycTG8uLiEi7tlI/UIRyqTV8DMe871yHxOfylpmlv5eMa455STwq@e15WIp0bE@EA@G/HeCScjVQAnvwOfrOQcZkFk79DOGvq9bWQKPVgKxObjxJZXBK4oPHn1jjH4aFXb3a5tkCmZZKX3Ktt@r26z99gB/l7dYK8qVRy01XEBkd/lu1WtVhEKi1bjya0oM7LgVrss1@OMOo2hafjS2nK2ThY5@mSDFYsO2FvelhhiONnyoP235dDP2vI8@PS/rK3XHpNxECSZbLdpn5hti2WrkP9bSUDnRPnwy79pGLm/@5Nfe9d41/jCgJZbsZjTjcjP9Z//HDysWbnuN7uoQxyXmKMhaK6xFccNay1oKeIZ1B3G/fuNN2yuoc5gdx1oveOXdIZ6DmVNg2@H1I6Rty1c2JogrZk2K1HKkhRol6QVj7qtBMFgW7gVPJRN6UL6CjpBZcoqIC6lr8xBgcUAqk@31fD6k9GQJsrHKJxeT7A7EARi@ApuNbVBC3KFzFVBTCW3rgflKHtENdKJ2MDyPNy4CmoR6SsQRGzbhSfcmrh2HH3aDgh5Db0QnuTQrkHcdYi7zwM0yDZGqeceEoxjxwM5oDlLXwFlgKhgg47A7G3wUAbB8hUgAKQhJgDbdbbN0gq7sOPx8nxXrEucdIxbl5n@ulUJgyG0Nq6T9gOX0R9YgcaOB8UgX4gcBvUsZOkD4TD4oGgFdH4MTl@odNHC8luDAli0iUuMksbu3JljVanYbYVRihD@qT3EPirKB2c5rgDMby990i7JCYb7jZV924DtgOJxQhe4TuUbjZVDQZmMn5eSBP9bMy1y5JWsIocyJkDkFy8VLSAZBEay8zxsse0K0428wgLkW4B7i5CiLa6CRuDJ9BPN@MJ3vAQMfx7xt2EG6XMc7vcTfHt14TKDam@Ce@Di9jVcGIgFx3yDGpRi@2M/dBAKkmL3yXfHHkEDhQZl/d2uYmldwWDz3cEID5pGbGQYzufNKviiUOibwdvEfZ1EPBu0N0XLhQz1hq5DG0HRphU4VRo4AmSU2E@Hoz1xznHPdJE3FDiMkUd76SDnI8a0sRUdNkdhcZSzOYJWrE@bBLO6GmsN2swoshgxGu374wTgFApECDdB20UaN/vWAFA6siyGeyF5pWSyC1rRpEmbHz2xga96D22oShwvKc71S57bp3byGPd8Vd0OqNBiKXkEFSksfnxAVWw01HfdU9a3Ty3enRtbWIjvMdD3QWlNAGXnNxC2hD3HRjrBUuCc4L7gzsMrz42FRCjsRmymXH@n9Y1YA3P0HdVJ9gjP7DsznRB96XoniSauN/P8rTxoQwr41gKRa4lF/JUorh8OdqeQxKYkFdoPQ8Mu/WEMGpz@Zh5oBF3cOmPYWJWwjgGh2fKXxWMphtR@hSoAKntQsnBfr/GohJs5ACajdqwFRU8IeId9wtKGhB75TitiVxSAgVlfWYQObhAU0@GN25AxGl@CBXIFSuegDW64jFiwH4b3uRvNtOfanL3ZhgCHlQ7FVWG8WPgf2dAHlg7kZ0r6BjjmAMMlmGzE5DiAjcuKzEEH4a8G59wukSwpseuQEgwhCFIDFFIV/EM9WWhzcwkc7pse3wFT7AB2fn6u0VZ0k5GtWR5u@O3hSaXJYdcGndhNjq3BUBytZOORegLu3KTyff7x/Nq7Uzo5tnhnxt@S1PEqYvpDLNrxolg5nuF@1t0BbWGDe8d4xFAPbdoLvxUTMzY4/xn1xIXPfyXkP7UQvUQgjCGYaWKWaCUAWKLZOk10zttl4XBGBRKAQy5aviVu/zjyPwaeb7KHncCHO6aFCf53s39KY5sASeZdp/OoeQp9nzP/U3wP7SkEcqxztjMambMYuSvoGxk4NiO1h82g2icXMEI1wy74XoT2tDarLwSfBsGhUvObPGyE@9NIF@uB8o0p0X3K3afgPuXu03mkfrS1aZ2rZGh1iclBrsdtzXyfCGbm@7nkmzjOXQgyKNZM5yDQ52zB7hLuVoVC@/TmX5CPFZ8xgCeGQHArlqy9PKmd1B3POt@qx5NdYHaZCAE5DqBrdaLpeTswI/X7Z/2h6y1YObibHdRKAm@0avUEN3BewTQGGUSMwell4wZk3YEYa@cKgUgwQEA9DBxRNdgZx2ylHOyESo7AODV5TmOOWE0gUyftSzgJO1CXOOk5YcOA6iFAaB8kCdAEF@aXHH68gy8dXozwFGvfr0o70g9wI5xoPQqUvFJUuKwpUyaFsFJVH00gO6qrlatJ8d0hK2pXnELJvBT5H0Z/46PR70C5WI49MSyvMMpSuKjgfDBQIURxIaqyaiWUr4BBcsvsWyOoufa4fipqa4hmK@k3M3g8mATvHM@sjIUyv6Xw/KGlYrIjlwJWmFUqkMRZhRdLXi58knKCB8E8EWzmM4IIzwUIwEgtDWaJYNNwsGmlwgUHm64Idh5CckpITnkQ7nu6Asm6CAatp@CwY8yeOminOPtMBng6r0ZBDRrKDA@uxJHr17hJF45SijjnMoe4QPAQqtjIZ6360thrIaRDQusKAGTEawDa/KSoknRV4Olq8BXIKE5KX0bxL8EGXFYAg5EILvONLGMBk1EbGBR@OU71AJRdOV6TZJ36dfGX4rec8C39W79umVr0qS9aphJXfv8glnWkbKiAhrQPPZVBgYwtmefiiO8FnSOChyr2XNDqmucuiy1RtsE@6Z8Onmz23WZyYOJsETw/JjgzXPHbDzgmwu4N3bE5djOZEm802cR2y@LnbQa767jQNAlvYAu6Xtu1PCc6hkxtuV3H9qwEnlLOVXaL5i7wncKlsJ4sjK4nSaIPkjdjETTnK1R1Gw080a7RiOE8M6UUTFylaWfIntGohO1fMIXCg3gSQA@GMbf52mqNlZth4l7LItix3TqNHQyFYxQi2WEgw1qg/4NrDzQY5rnzliPt@oqqdHMco/3oe@7A7YLWN/E0CUNfAb8/h40ImcMh4ZJgJjZpS6Edt6mUxFoJUxFBP/vooOwzI2YqQXhjEcACMRJsdJXGSNnRkugaK6Pjwfz4jj4e36Mwvkfr8aVW@FWcedO8wh0/Lup0bA4BPM7RSN@MBiYd5Fb7GjoLqATWqFfxALdGsU2zsdqI6Q543RHetQ7wRyL48uArQPzzVfRfn4F@8L3bZp@Jx3wezUDeDHCSYIxOCvD8wc0YeN9XFCmyJLqAtR/cMi7wi4e0PEQVAtRYElwOblgJBXMIzW4v2EbdB3wDz@Okqmt8TzOtKtxxCU6jswQ7NVZn0YNG2@qbM6sdEz4TIbh@ig@hwUby6nYJR0FHQs/lbb0Y1F1K4ArVOBKdeyqtYBkzcaYoq9mKe7ED7qGecsJwfzX90P2aaMYuvgrvrYZ2QDSKm6c5ZzZ2fw5nwxnfE7nPD3gQcpTXPzwncUH8zQQBOogtYRLzaJV14vMwFiTpFjVC4FdbTDJuWepDxN1Ar@fhx5Ho5pRC5oYCVfxclhb391@e4/a6HA9xhc@TfNzodix5E9PdmudCrMaBzUXY7sdVIdcg43yMVisWhsht1uaY61yTCWhH/XTOilqlsUSgBiFJ0o1tam6TfqFI2DLehzd2OH0ObwTYtcYNzlB@2rBPS5y8wshlYA5DWouwASUdoISoyEku0Aj5knwzeL@4DOJsrYyzdS3O1kKcQQlYjDLkSWotRClyAbNnXRb0rc54hXRGJ2w7w2ud2IbLcc0R9lZcRO1oyU6w6Fm0BAI5akVLezEQytF2tPSADF60dESG02jpMzDMy1b0XbTkFwv0MIJPMtxDeyHC8bsVLe3GlEtpbJ5anh@vFi0FeQp@7vJPogiQAtMNWiMOsTmuSOZ4ZEHFRkplgiHHeAlsPlE/TILuFPz5iR208z86Yh/nFnlmcaYvVBqhGoPHA9WGv7P0kpJcErX53sFDms8UeMFo4tDGC4ch8KCGR6KLwogjhq40ogFvQBDlZmk5RixUk90SHRE7cChl8mL8RD2N9IF2jNxr4Lk@j4SOaRHh/fxaBMEz8HZ4YuBVeF5Dx4@OMMIxWWUJWkjUV9E1icK8XsRF5H44h6ive9ETnpPre@G5RGBDMh10OBqcw8iG7nCRScgV58nb4TDUKccLJXLvlWAkFUTJXOFM1iJlKBjChV9Zl5xQOERtQQShYy1V56UsqBdIFqPTXNaFNFVe@ACFkMyBEm61TukInAfCSP64uElQXbGqGvLD8ihJci2KSQis4c4@E3PMYw8ar3u438/HNV/9kFPsa4khgFDIIBYuX92P0N9drr/7CrVPhCsRLFOsl1el19XrtbXsFcz782ivZyA6JtgDZalyFMQwJzm0DkKa@Tpeu6bi45QPruTzSAPoV7R9n2xBm@AGul1tW3BYqCWMzhYtTw2wPDVWE@q6RtI/03ylRcOYBBye8ADTedLW48oTviyL0YX6t83@R2fwaDGDw5mH8CgBoysk56V8NHFolsu8bIPY5jYoUvUS44KchkuDbJ5bgrinodtg2BYsDhqHDw6ePv46VLr5fF4RdfRsjh@WWuxrDepxDpkmRwf1wZJmi5HAUy1wsBu74@lM6o0TR74mS7iwBmXAhFh89hNlXBGyLCTPr5RdCMf9higqYJ3Oi4G5IJVQ1TGxyrYFXcdAEGsc2zIFEF@9BXonqLWm0PkNjQaeQ9xoUPXVaODkpUZD1GKYNf6IuPLzyEZy4o3oHER@@Mi5JNGSfPbggL14tHPMjh/tsYfPdz9jXz94zl7sPD3GpdXPnt9/vL/L4N57erTHpIXpkXhQEzYoga4PrJaFB@rhtmgZRpB33eGMy53YrsLtj8wBe@S2LBym2vbMwb0e/9Aca1zlofagOTrDPkybDuMa2GOcb0EnSUEzFpWbNq3Dw7n8DPw2oU07wDbvwG3bHRv8Stj2HdqW5y8HY30bchDkrb8GNsGVJDw0iqYO0fFuOAPrHIKb4B/HbgCMyedf0VHPtscDWG2NCcIF10dT8Hjv8MkRw8X7uwdPH@wf7x88PWIPDw7h89nX959@CvTcPzo@3L//HJ3I45ODB/sP93d3yIIjkNIYLp9/PfHGa1HQ0DtRpXWKI990onfwtdjrjRo8OzdpRaLHohMHpY9t9u23VjtaliYeqi@4CpKGClhsc@fw08@hzmfWGxzh9IeCaf6B/Nyjw8s2U2ybYoPCUoXyVhbFFao9VVdoPGIwY3iWgVWmlfIxMieYD5wm8bRti8m7OEcF@775gnoqyz5oiGgDYCMof8JKhdEZJNFoYptAViG2Vt/FLRF5bHwSofjAoPf8qSZliSgm5sogUFyvsO9gf5BeDiyA78HCENGOR9wDSwcW3APLcAtURfdx7gjLCh@T8cEExTPLcYvXg@FDGhZm@cDivkmt2ILAiecbZanJgjOccHuBPp00w3t56AQ802vZNgXxyD@ewtLv84Jh8fO/QCbyoUSa2wY@ZRA2HRxqENPe@EmZ6ArcgPOEzM7YY7GKorFjnBxkOTY/46fbNx0@BWo@dYd4jxVwA5mKmGZrB2fj0AqQoUsMiOdyLeIRhHsgtELrtuEg5P1rMZpijiSdT@dPQbsJgfvXEPhFwAAgdaGl06KaihaeIhi3I1g55rnAkdhv@z7sH9i5PWlZCwHErK3Ya/vtW0UQObHQTvLnKRJ2kEVvrRGolTSU2XFHUMZJrNJpIigFWz13OLZ5HsYWU0AjTlTNgW@s2CC2V5XqQmxIh6sxOq4TirQJXLwi1iYw5W1iJY7nY@eB@JofLQmcD5Uwn3eH6JhNPNF6PnaWwEGkcwu7X0ARprFy7PycjQkTrn9Kc9nxnuHpdIVK9cH9E/X9qwQeUcfFAj8V0p90iDcwJsYFxYPG@WjC4gj1LlHS/KOFvEkTQ4s5eEJaYin3gUE7sGdDu@5eoxy48enG1@1xjcxVe7J8967CQ6komcRBoV4vNpduCVbzo0xQmDoTU0BCshOQBVkf820SBDOQ1/dwXQzmQhko4qAcwXb7lYN7hAjxU9ecdECyiPMTRXYH8BVWpRkV8@NkcWVLOD@SL2P3K/GqkpxPKGEhcsZ8EZ3wIeuKEpqWQvXVNXAP1oMD@X17cIW12PHq4aOgPVgL7aNwU@OrYfFqKQTr9mDfrwHLK7dfCCykPbEaMK8kr0MLOD1gzsRmJJhNuz7GV9fyjsoegMG6F3tQAqCh2CYODVH7GxDHeAAlDGauEB0dP9g7PGQyb59AWJB72GRoCzGIsDfYs/lsW9shYacFSlPQWA6UJ99mYUabf60rzEuJt0JUCB0kIegRCIv5wckde8qlnqhZSIWg2fckEH3KLWJ34csgryYAX0IbEJCdZ1oogdLSZEZ45WN74Unggm4JrhuH5/DTDGted@OphKNZGFB4TpDZxZUly/PvBdePS348XMHCDW8wwW3QpKG@gXbCEUQ8BI@atpiDa7LFz1KcZM8V7IhPO5z4lVrUsP/@DEWMxJVwrguHxLpQjgVqXD/e9NUcmpCI1YCJMz2FI5/RDA6@iCeb7XCGKvNKL7ZYBYGSiefU3QtzBQSvX5aDk9Nj83qyEijk4bK2SdjUfCzr2DsrYJf/n@KebattZMtn9BWFTIIFsmyTQAjGJAZM4h4uORiSZhniFrZsfNrYbsuA3YFZZ@ZhfmDmfT5hfuX8w3marzizL1WlkmwgvTJrddYKllRVu3bt2nXbt3o80wu0hV5LTg/JqmC2fbKqzP9PVbxKxGpSNJ/ZGJUIkNdWV189BzvZClU886OweQ1Jzp@j6wGc7yOQ4SQk8T5wbuXQVekRAzxBOjatVwMmURC2OjPWlFjbaTEy8QNcWC4EyGDgb7z6L1mrI8YJ3GZD5xXJhE5ZptpgDGHdUB41U9R/eLo6nJCfrW/@j9fHgw0zoengA1rlH/SHYRB55RlRVIxP6L8a/xYMhz3Kxv5M1wglTW5MTzrbkbcdG7xyqzCR9G1mS1rSO4nNbl0la6BKSLzo4W2fKN0rJMV7mXzBbOpeZb8sliggXysmi7SHtmPMPfOd3lMI0BxMcglcPsiH70W4Af8BB1eBBDKRN1@aaOM8ixtRBHbNNbqMRZqFyrk1n@z9VtjwexjSw7VfhMJ2X0JBksKWj/acWZL1XCFWHpALB700lHLtjGdTUfiGAl2EFAfBvYnfjQULPTWUpeQTd7T72fx6bu2tRa3ruSP3uvb2wl1qFG0Bi6/fuw5vhnfNX9v9q9uW6IrBXy/Hjcnvvwmx@lq8grpWXnIw1vxaMUuRLN/A33XxNkecKxF8R4Flz20hPL4XTohFEZ3DC/OC70SjQ/MGekgkuFQsXSsuRBe7UfG6tnZR7BVzheta76KATn6j5eJoOb@cxg8vYRWFOYY187XRBa6pptQ16N0KvC6UrnWTriGCXEPgy4E/7PT3S4cfYtI43ACgCEzaepNAnW/6nENrNvQ98XrBXVqKyVyBHGvhBsmaI6@gPPq0kzwZxTHNDmAGveLCbjYc09@JY83lvJvBqE8pKjAfspa479xbc8qNKUcSBchS66jwfXTBeTiO8qRRMcRfJ2xFncnzdi2PvpOOAaKGJWk6tM9tG30KEVHpy1W7sEIv8BtXiARebXtPxcTmJl10C6wWeiTFQ1MOf0gOE7kLfEQFCPwMSNuAVdDOPSS3Dwuaj@95fOAvJKMakZ8MGchbtFPEFDT/Ft/Iv4nKbwIBmPBzvOfypIhT7rxgI8m@gyRcwOhk8YM/qhnQrZI7ZQ4bi7C5vmIEnCzFiUZYrSQTfJ@7Q3IyreCfbEEmT29TzdD5Hc5OJCE9tXwLkZbUpZS0hT/dqFjaKJZRxVRmgxRzz1IDJV1wPDoIYFhNxE7Q7QLSTIu5iBz4SP69sv5lXX9YwzovNPKcnplKz8TSPU5npKJcHizwUaYNM5Od@hblexB2lM2dqqsoaPPiQU83PNiSRHkLT@UNvVG/3okyb@muZK7UCZuxhIyR8nVG73PKfKyMZnCdXuN0yd8rsuc1lrG87@P1468lOygg41lpa5LgUq/X6b7jRUunIJvZQE0huDj2N7EdD0rpgymnE9jBoZyfhu1WMYKynFczDo0Ze2vzve3JTca7dBIN9mKcGlgzxohBJapzmQg3JodFqIeS5w0QBBMZTaiRu6UKT2ThiQEWc82ratkLcmqAQ9OSQ7yIfpH3@EcN9jhyKl9qduIcYz7mxrN3c5xANOnO27PJFJ9N0F2EP8pGPbGKRHVPkhBnTxKHhhRY1xmwD3YLxeDzep4wJwo1U0zRXadISkcZ8op9H@tCTHyw/pldsj74sMcedIOxKOExwycvLCvm4D4KwlGIsZ0oFk14Mxh0UetIG747cqGWgUJWVlHdEkE0VnbPqqBlD@d38Uk6pEMhTxwh5Ds0EIkSwpt2G53J0AO2f4dTK0pcOiPPKvUmLNCAMfNqhd3MA3ETstYUTvttEwnuOR49SOlw4DcCz4I9Wgi7H4ub2uLxLeXp6DeC0cNgSduwrL/cdBq/7nxAfe6bfO5V3iDZrVQH57xXryMHKyCSSljJwTZ2Nf/asgzdcIN1wxkE6Ip9XOg/A28Gt0GvF1glWDEoYwib1jAY3gZNz7KOA60ERrjIyqiZRD/s/s2wwcId2HT5wIzoJRy6rA4DDsNfXJ9ZXdwgXZlrodIq0jZDV992mkhA5XHS6qN2mBQWGCaA6YGFroMREGXJEXGUSPcscaG9yzUKooAaGOfE0E1oMvT6o04DeoYkWVYXQLEaJKqs10xgAvU1uj46B3uzEED3mIgCCgGlSnoKB0sqzf8QDkI2TOnYfdUzWZj9@jRWYLgHww7MvhGBqVeomIE7dPDJx0pVVI/2Tr6UjssCnj8dH32u7JZ3xfYZ6bhRUU5hbsXHo32YXbQ2nbXmR/DBLlWhpE0JVunwTJR//nRcrlbF0bGoHHzarwA0AH9cOjyplKuuqBzu7J/ukvYdIIjDoxOxXzmonEC2kyOXalXFrKicONoTB@XjnY/wWtqu7FdOzqjGvcrJIVaGWv2S@FQ6PqnsnO6XjsWn0@NPR9WywIZZu5Xqzn6pclDe9aB@qFOUP5cPT0T1Y2l/P9HQoy@H5WNBRgJGK7fLgGVpG46wWBO1c7dyXN45wQZFTztAPEBw3xXVT@WdCj6Ufy5Dc0rHZ64EWi3/5RQyQaLYLR2UPkDjrPQzVIF@2Tk9LmP8I6RE9XS7elI5OT0piw9HR7tE62r5@HNlp1wtCGv/qEoEO62WXYEXxlHVAAOoBenwvH1arRDdKocnsGacfkJ7Bwc6@QsQBrAsQdFdIjCaQWBrgUhHx2cIFelAHeCKLx/L8P0YaUrUKiEV0KJi58TMBhUCEU/MZorD8of9yofy4U4Zk48QzJdKtexAh1WqmKGCBhlnwDpQ6Sm1GvsJ8OJHYFZLca5L3Skqe6K0@7mCmMvcwAHViuQWItvOR0lzD6PhGkKUTh9lBv61KVhpTX@6DTC45LREZraMRkdM2jnaLcOKLINV2VHCKaw664lQSmYarDQ6EV5jIWuaweVNu97ptfroY6qLseDjOmy7ePOKgxdQnFtPXHAh5StUIJWq1z@X6nDQrdbrjvs9JWNoPFdCisGfyuXINmJsfTx5o@BnY4Ppvhkj1NZLqegkQz1UQGBOpv5LNn3zrwNHZLPNQBZD530ErERHIatNrlCVAlMjOTviLRlRlSSZoPeOZAcqmFbgvUYd5aRoGUmZ@iH86d1HL7w4GB9gdmZxVzaLh1hCo/N7oKrhSigkAv2REQk6LarSC4Pg13Y6Z1aHZ36v3e83046jylDeEZwD22nnmeKXQTtRPJMsT8iS2lmG1Q/VuZu2MFr/LEkmZL94Q2pZGv/UR/TjKGw45gNKTakqElZLoWX6JRdHiyRXyNAW6F5BnYx7voPSz5UveJrLrbwuJL5/1N95bKG9IAahhQWvRuUu6OfjBWeAAUaxOIAkHRkhI5s1yih7E535DjJeYaa7ThMtf2CtvgpoXQeSwEb2xu@adeJqPOyMTexhHv5wXDrYPt3bg6kTsX29vvpmrWDpsFs/u/x7hvVQpFiKOjaAdRz2aZRkjJId2PjQSDFiaUfsTwyczWJGDLmuOo0@YpwHbbcRt2TCiQybG@KVMT000bMDpIMtKADHvKX4debIlAyQjjXVwdZc@2Pa4vuwVyIekMYs3Qn12hj/IGw9/NUQ1w2SDCRZjGLnAufC6YLmPXtPmYrS4YYC92AWz1Z8zGHcNA1I1EX2s@hdS2@St41eDNmUEccrdTuVBCTmk1gIZVfR45H9ieKMSAEwRQ@DLz9LfoPHMxngjsLd@eGoNKoCGfd0SZRTR8Jo2eiahHyxVYQuevlS17QpUMrvSKRo7Elxsg4MYowGQgXvCUEb3zjggo4jkqySLGDfLzriG3MqBu9AOAXJsfIdOHdWcySUgoofIt9VVArBsHSQE6bana7DUlnOdBwLRc4YmX6IHgT/T6TJDPibcOIE6BG1jCCA30VJgsq0guMrEaVzpxQNhnYjoqb56SwC82B2zJVumNTejNm/Bkgge2eiPpxR2MNWegYBkMlRsGGOX22SduXD0em97cjiqCfpNa4HaSHXCrVUTMHNrF24tO1ylW4FXxzhsKzJqHAfior3fHC7pFEPR6bEUV68CG0G56j4H9klEoDoAU9cesVWq0nOyslRpuYBGWrJWHCaOmISbEsfHtXaLQkjRGZs7peaL0UoAL2F@Ey3k@4C6Qs2z41HXKSVWJxQFDyMB47HZFx8ZMi6SzLE7AYI50WThCF4XcjoDheILkOnUH0RNJF@QYYiWElkdRjFGcTp1vGAtLSs3mnsSTKJHKqxP@1xIPqApVoqh8cBPiSGpru8Jw78CaDc/b5mM4tll6p9F20XsTIWS8jyeDVKo98fwtbRx3YDjm5n4njiixQ6BL3wZijjF8J61hlKiYTa9EM1uG3i0zstMxwDnlALOyP0Vmh6xB/UpOsALUQ5PMk4sybSwLyKR7eU0LEzXs6L9GaUsgk0obCkRMRNsSbu7zkXE1SGDA2Igp1QHy7IZpPqQb2DHn53/eGvuPbjFqjXDJo6MqkBkmSB3EmVHsV4bIy46epOKOgKlIBoSuRZkKYNVWGNfiPZSdo12VF0TIxdSi354/VoJlXWUlBRxLiydmC@tQx0JlJpRYYG1cFC8yurhMqsA9fDo4cxihYaV1sL@7ynp5QN3kQUX6itIz7xvKmfzvBJCvmLL0IcPfAFddxyC4oI454V9arT8xzhhzYFXzrBsGnKRGEn0/QHKH6jo0@/R7yoRIcy7F/DH4XBBE4AjWxnnCUY9fRP/atefaff9dudfseHcxqGcR/zjIePE3rEDmsP@3ch3fpDCU0jU3MSPXN8GQ7Dhu9aL1kwQnOFo2CQNs0URsNJ6YrDRJDkHI0Ao6sfib8HyRhpuszr1aiQFfc/JXu8vFN4tOyr/KzCrNFHAHKC20pYULAP6Ygckwzn08JUhsunMhg4XoqM8J1HLPZiGL8FEpEaJoaxQmbKLMFsBJ7MHsW41hy7TYpBOMRAS8FugFfOhGn67Pp4yS7MIu/QUmBD5NdzRlHWoowxDiE@TB4n98qbPxl7QOAH0M@/msUtsxiBpriWirYU8nlFRhkFXMg8sENzNM3EMIt12rAKdWNA6@Mk1Hjy5DFqkOUPbIpkmL0prsQRmYaDD14kl67DlFOfOLioLIpFh@J24BakNErnHmfY4Dn7WRr8qMRlyRlOTDsSctpA@jFSNYBKeJ9owrzWRJljKj8/YlZWvrfXEgQszjI5M@7NTdtq50IeKB1eX1Gt1R/CZGwnqCdNPRbDUX@w@J3Ue3TumBmZbRatG47zrCEwM1sRFsulJpG2OMHHScFK4pNgmjjFyNIMeAiPr/Ss2TxJxHGxjuOtWJ88Q4fHaBbZTelFRfd3k8c@Loq3aNGrFho9pAh3DFJa0N9rdWh4/fEZRMLk41WdZow6Thn1CT8aoBJk0lT6fgoR90ncE/RoAuWw3ibQzuyfR4maNJJTIU9VUizIJdITA7ej0ybMS4MWGl9gmDje4epJSm84x@6EVHn5zCUGGcYEBoi74iATyaFYght1VoKP6HaAVrqO1kJ5nIngacu0cNBB/zXBKCq/FO5Ii4f6JJO/KDCksYYEpwrK9RQk5W8Or7X6mKBMkQKG@AxS6BZNzU1X39@qH20L5AMIXJqSpaVvzsXGOGIZsIE/ZlJ9jHvgqCpZMjai4gOhTlMDjAU4pbS7AR9XcffXGTLHo3WDHEZwgODPafxZliUwnPdaTlMbi4ybE8ziSHLzaHNEZouLRAzF70h@ORR5q0sHVwAQMMZQvpgHCBjWlLBHpQCF3jE5L4ao7CMoWMzjsISPFBU1svOckY5ElRlerxo5crNyvDVhZGYCgY3F7DwRIrBnmZ0lggIL3UxcjBxvZrcnygEbYsX7THHoCtkrcRrqnmMCwiNhq2eUWl64OcnBlPh61Yklav6m1Lc5IzWXTAX6aAxrmXwydT0XS41Vu7ISLxorCfRwzFpjiUAKx0RYzwo/9o9cU8yQ59om1DhkxHYZ0j67h0epOzy3eX8NxSY5Zas9hoJneoar41edr1iJBWV/OgC7WCSVAcZu/@HWKstUhYm8K4Di0ilnlzQfCGnHauNSj83Ck66KtKcDFKgzbb8lPp/s7cXCvl5OlKHRdTBczeVyyMSXZvB7ZVuNoqROPxvPnW3ddLvZwd1Pw8@XWZr7g4CuBNhQJ@gAugQGRej1h22@GQJxgKyYOyMdWfGsf9NqmVcwoIYSOw@6jXPKaAiCFqCONnr5fEICIAIpF9hfsIHYvl@EHn13Pm80JRSlhoLSaBJ8ayvtGZAHP7TQPltrqggYTszKmgnWLae49Q1XELzZhDqLwhc73yLzZPtj0O32XfEF7w3GSAFzD8kCe3tmgRxnQQ0jeffehBSP1hXBbadr@BVjFpPXEZxamNQ9EyouPMbGPw7a5fEgbde@2rCsQJOXsZnLGJ/aFXbbdmSw@O8Ay3wIaH9X7mt/kG4QnZKZYamXIzh6Aoxe5d2ZZ59YFodkYpJmz@dGos5G16NgDdB0h/YCKpY9dS@15JHsmrj2@TjfQhrmGIbECWOufF8JdDX786bF21Gr9X2zIl0DwB37h2ZEvgnlxyZE0gHQCJTDD@iJUbT/JQPDei8RUIQ3OHhZx/S8gwXqWMCyXjSKv92lS6WSWBgsL4tSaRseMhlR2i6JXfywvS124X0b318WV1ZXCzzn7jrf4OO2@vggtgEGSTiXG1fDXXiFtCL6jaG1NnbxQra44BYW6sXNrUKYrZW20a0fnv7xb//xj3//z2xJvvw3vmzTS@2rzuR5Xnah8W3h5UMB32u7F4sLl7WFwcViu4Bc9k@KGt6vjDJ@ZD7qDS@tFK8CxleyI1XnbIo@I4sKdavftT/8FWaXDZFqhNmU/BryzVE0x6YagfE9QD/KSzjCq0sHkkd5QCIFQCcojofeaQRogAfrDVAScEE7UC7PuhUluMdwMDqD1qqkZCQe2rPeBujTEkVSQF9cWLEynV4Y9FACfkt7Xm6eZfnw2xnVJf9mvx6E7e3@WCydp8VSTiy5Ysm26Se/9ha@OgvZDnrncjY4Dti2CymRagHNDEXYoY0enR/orp0EuS1rga7sQUgqTAVlZi84V5/@yFmGL1wL29YcXpopWERCSiYskvq20HuAbvkGOR7smKsNbRTq8hRDlRkaFd2/uAXyQzYEiGq@ZoJs9KFK1PSRRzI@ZdUX2dcW3SZEgJGsxx/2aNzjB1iLFnrS5jl2lsJrjsh8nr/i2lhgZ2hCG1O4/ggBUqjwcTJHnoSLqUWLrbyNVlIz2QvbbJ9kPrZ1mAQjZZvOhf5VGEzA1twm4RZ60q9FGnKzekXYHa1eMaqyk7bfwjKKXN90R52BdFeg2nFAfdO1PfBIwh4lQAyHY/ZvTI8wEhSoSFGJbuHLsiai2cem80joSdd06GDHY82RQYTs1zSM7fvE2Hay5CWi2IF5gJDSpnwtv9MNZdSVIRG77Q8v8XZAv0UXqo1Yb0byPLwmNYFxv6WR9ggymZxH4xmakhoM/fa174rUYf9k6E8qsGzBzmfU8BxoIYZgQiRw8MmqZzVPIcwtkl1CFNFNIcshvLygO5HXo3Hf2trnBLtUDQUZdgUHQYydiJLBfayvEnSMuPoPdIKJ8tTkrbWRcoqlmRctjSQk23SboWE2NXQsVYM5dvTAsS1GVY9MxQuy0A0utNek@IWZvIsxAmTdtvQClK4Ia2@xflyd2kHPjy1Og66lHP2zBcHrIo5nuoqSrZEsdfNpPrrxDrGCfeTXeBQIXptUOCNrLp2eOw/ldW4pcx2hIN/aFj/ri46@gI4uMCPPEHHa6/BkmVihojswPFEhy3@A0Or6bcBvcudPkBXPU@l381mn9vW8d7GUPu/dn//uECZySlarbEakpDJbzVhyrMDKmHVjr8oqLVShBs978QznPcE@LAYJAJFsuvY1e3GfBYTOU3in/HmKCRLrMsQk@3R9WQSfnUIzFccim7LmnCVHdX76Xd4RsLbSL/Yhf3D4F7BQh0oS08M5Z9gCUOSn@9sNu5yE2fWV3OuV/Gs4CbWDcWYY3OB6mwlvLoMxbCVCPM7C0nP@e4wbYoR4GId@AT6OoZ18rQn7noTSSUlOoXKYUz2WZiso4zFPQH6gMoVLRRcXR@fxUfmIB35XAMupvBQLik0HDe5L4/oZ9q@xHj/EeS3pHcIciVYGbCNCItQMQlaXrzzGoY4aLovk5@SJHYzdSkCge7MpY7Xo9XsZuVlzvMUCbqLRa6a7nlvPJcfo1BCNjdAFuZlanBf5rXdv/v5fR7@lRqmtleyXIfyOUr@l1tZT/AgP8PZKvd2mtlKbmG3tITXJwhkYHt/8/X@g/NZPAAdTJpvwZ2tVwVqbpLYyRSpyn9pag4f8ygrU@79/@xu0YYFPbHgX60LdFYRYQVFkx@8R70K6qGAr@Vi6GE0r5JiFMNjCEM7m8IKGUeOV9RyJ6VLSquI2kJGvlD2KXOLJMGtEpkIsyVD2FLAz4gJFrCDDIJUJRUsYthvKbAOZN0JT/PLCWwvhBPCLNOfQVWrTjRchmgwt8LEIOjDNNcJ5nh@2cu9sbd6xYSubkoLaQuLRTs61668K/wc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/76wuf)

IE4 is separated from other browsers with `[].pop`, which is undefined in IE4.
`[ ].pop ?` is on a separate line for DOBELA, spaces are for Retina and Chip.
IE4 requires `d.body.style.color='000'` – it is the same bug as in IE6/7, but reversed: `body{display:none}` gets removed,
`*{color:fff}` is not.

Answer (score 3):

## 309. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE4), 14380 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa



























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:8][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}* +a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
*+i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[os]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4ocod""n;z c;op>s'0}e}eq67+?4[0][ ] 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKk9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vq9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrdGGrs3Y3dN28saaUlCX7uj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d0LcE8z5lgX7MBp2W2AxMbumeXYb6wRuGUYu2/13w7ejlnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeypCR@dSeuMmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2DOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1zijMokuBscfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@2j3yafX/Osp9qkJSA371vRa9LrOntvWqH09hME@P3nw4Lptmn2mug57cBMlPcN2J2P3YHwdfpbtdi3HZIZW1Izrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD2wR5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILL@xxT4MAJy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@x1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mZNbtwR5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQma7bzUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@4ue5QiUbKeL6Xg@t0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwhOhi1x7bR4QLt0WvTIiytNoLan5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4pyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@cFT5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@4/uR9l1YCM2qgpBSStsEvGWMR3ZOdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttjHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2Z5wBS7dtnKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SriQoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3HCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9KzXE6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKYLBPTQvbDmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDmwiR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOUe6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSfRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurEz1nPHSwmjYuXgyDpPRurgP6FOYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrngPWdp3oOIByMYLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyTVCadJ1QnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjrM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUgWoY91XNnsDjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@sYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyW5OBr0wI/jgXJ3nv6dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qju6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrN4QNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gVdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzjIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92I3rwcX4tdvkl@lnA4KW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSY3kw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@TUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4hbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4GdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Rqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfwuSOJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMe6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9HriFH702a9vR6M6OFltorTzo3R6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPABBczxzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vY/cK7JBpBmdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abK3ID1GTJ3uUWhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAT@QEhRQBotkUtSfaEFKHncjdYZbThzqHmAxroEo7DJQ0aECiBEyNugcdsseN4SWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsK2Hl3u9H0UBSg2eNlBARiTZ2j8dYNmIKpBc9X3FsQFsCTq1U2eW4N4ISR99XEngCskoOcrJPWJHPT@yzSft6RjtoiZ5kLHWgK9mtsVyWoPLnpaGyjqrRBaqC8h9FqiLzYngCfYN5yRYzVBbeRpaHWm9FoBLK4RhiIHh1KYl4UGE3Z@i9WasvVAJugsLOpVET0D8TLfVAECWETuAX2hsllQPB4sDhsKe7Jw8roixyx2TTdkoLFn23ZfbJehO9y37YRwf3jnaPvt5YAqNvN0vXLZJ2ppDDqnYyVbvOJJnRjNJmGMYc8P3GetgYcNGPLAlnprrTkKo0a0HlMvXJeXj02XWSgCaE5KAYwIz3NZWG@wGlS2qaXu9aJcy68ThEGQTx/TL1gPkwAwOiju6mj8/TyZs3mHnXkRoKe8SsPzE5AN8yeeD44TR0vKaA@U7NDq8RKSxoobaD/Z9zU9inj8@nqDVfR4ZU6RDLfHr4YP@oQmB7pndm9fsqeUl6Y9ClzFFbA57vT9qWtMwPiD8wtVhcmyOO@jThupTArdYCged5y1bABwDYxNFcpvYHftK8HuC@dz1tZKu2Ag6gb4JwXa8M60Otj0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhXlkFVktrrMB1sdpqZbNWPlMMV1uteZztMNABKcW26@uNI3A681S00eZapFCrBfrHj24g7pESCU0B1cfM6zON4vL6ErZeVJtFveQetNDcvqU9J4knM1lJJqN@x6fW8qjNGfK/P7XHsZTC37oCfiH23d0D477vWXTUUQcGNRqwCY4106iDAw0tD3jEcftu12VbEIZrh36EoDatTOZu13Vu5JCJlpjUCI5cgPzF/hpzCHWN/YYajhQq3Fzlox6m412AlNZzaSQSUYhAJcm/9so8N4Fc83QfH3xjHyoRPZtKBeYUXUCCUBgiF5paIVuyYCpEpAl8liYwGMW4Udp9BzU0jICJFoIuCLg7d15qSRJTSy71vxSlr7o3KP7KnV1jLbDhrAWGEMkOnjx9dPBk//HuF6djI5td@M6kijkgHMTXBF1I63G6YWnd4kUTk4XgIlA2Rli8QApMoIHid4dPvBEIbg29aByBFVzDx39iX3V7TtRTrifmAl3VV06Ls9BjLHzcqwgIDe12HxsjIz5shvU58k9vPB56pWQSSnlv0tSg0Zp81XL7ZjdJ4aBi6PeTOjZdDg6xX8NbFgKQ8WYWD8H7tEB1mFHHodkfuNB4oaE4FA0sxsFTZ1Xf7vagLYzjddZI0QIOptQk29BCgLZyMkgbCWD6AtqKt59PMmftr@hGgfO1njIySdn3tlD8we9Gx4KmUwxqKyCFcu2Tnd45vcNmIKUR0nUgEaZtiSEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9HqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDraljD4yILe9wkkNV17cXrq1EFBP71DuOFAWG1Wr@l1pcxuBtkS/pUycO9C8pB3fQvgXTICa9KbrZBnbfOmOGubVLraLDkeDEWdow7Z411QpN64IK/bVrjsYYBk2DG5teA3iZ7fJZd0CPUxqIQPpFQSChTUtMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQBs3pvB08GHn0NyBBvdyPe2G/Worx71Guwk9YZAROpjbqGU9rB/cAy1Y8D5KKUhc1FIswsrit3npsc7KSGQGHT0w0NbLYBAnfFBR7QTDLYCE1Aoap6D5AC@wt7S3ryXERv9wGkQIeGEnQ@gQTg0aNAFOQOBeUJ2eUJ4TGSzmKQzx71wEFrTYgW1aY95H787GeFgnt0Opw28pw3uB6BR4kJynUb9mlaL97LywJQKaASabGANXOxKAO2KRIFFSTD5iCG2BT3sqIZilVJx4ATgq@zuHkixlsX7i9QBNqKApfZZdDxK7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVJn43PIBNmX7iE4B6IoMRbOolET2gpJ24A/L0nPpb0PGer@5Kw9m4BykGDpPNiju0nOttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sMrqxsREtRavRBJh2wLSNph00xcG0QyaVTOhPQxOFSJAJXWsUAu3q0auaD3mq1JEHpqg5vLGHMbNWKqXrCbOmi7eBbwWyAigPvlV8AZyoUqmgUVHk6gUO1YD@Hkr7HvLOcWtkDwUJvgoKAf8WNEgTEaB5j9r8yCpj23Q9RQaVETQaLVQxY6PoaS11Wj@9PG3HT6@iCQytlM0KtA9BeI1jA607cidDUNxqmZIKsk2ppUv1crMSTUW3YrGC2oeITEX5pKDETU7rWNQCnoqdnkaBpII6tVZvRPCmCUNRAkIBHh0bWhn9fiyqXRYg/qZSV@JRCKtEEyCWK9Eo0KWFRPAo0dgjwJnogT0FUkLBhCouPKZAApLGpLC4fsMa9majsIeg1w20bOxBnw/GQ2EgKR6Wkm94@LBCt9DS9/Ve7g@UW@y8Q31pOOPSXeKYniYXJob49e652hm4YzP5uQaNJi1UXUY3oklVhZqQXDgkSvZj28MibDqWO/HCPY1LO0AxdrA96U1AWPqzZhLAVfZQslo9l0U37wJ0FgzzYFWCI1YqH/fyAbRbGtwoRFErwcES0C5oOokNchGnmvBeGZ2Q4KLH75vP5oavtSC2MoVhKYzI7jruyFKBJBBCoskfNFVIqjIxo@SAer5ujEsIV6rSsOFtWyARH/Rdk2jLxXVoPGg4CIWH9jkEObLaUh/kRwfEo8bzYmS1k1sSDc66ox7UEJAalMRGkFsD4ZB0vWFbG08hqBTDCjfsyFt3oHResLZhGLlWtlPy3ZArgNg9yCRslTrQxPWdVB0cFZHJ@7xbyG@jPzm8v8/7TqiyxeoV@9EaA7c9Ab1StJuOLKebYPvAT7bjDmwggx/@zVn/yHXHvJUPH6t6Znij2R5M@ib1@VzvllkbruU23T51Ba0LOvc/GXlm3@SdUL7r7uePQdd/dnJc0UohT0nzfLA2buyHXB4tp@dBeMyRhln94SGPM6a8mZWx3vIno6GYEQ45dJiIqWiQR759Hu39IoVjKMK@gPYDnIYGurLoRaDPwFJ4LJJHnJqGM3qE5aWeukL7lW2wwJ9O/rjiOMf2UjfI/nzc6SxYp8n6TEXR1J9bZ8iaT1FbaCOGUcpyTzhfbcFPGFCO/ATT1q77E8IrmGLQs/r@COIRKCY4SgZ1ex/VJ2iboCbO545ZoEgPcTCEJDQOsbEW6JrejW4LKFNDlfuWIhtUTqAOS6LmIm0mmejiLlNJcVwxNOlx6elC0556T7arfMAam04j3mpL8s73zQaA2K6W/dlEq7xhTNFo4I2gEm4QgpJJw/Y3khpMwvCoT12iIGXJS0KrYWqk1NNpfr@e9IgIHSafnk4/SRlfQOMD53xt3kl2rTJGt5Ja9M37oVs9EBssPl0kGeTDxOm4/bbKB70g/xlvLmFGiKkGwawzEvhgY4/8CWc2TmIREwNBXIbmqt2Aey3rqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyyt2eJ87esBjXYueYN@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@ZZlPBBaUIHeqaKAlhSkji5jCLpGYREoDqcjevkULmW0ajNhAxhnDnL5XfpsW5OMjF5B9JGZAh3UOEhpiegqKjlNJ9htvi@O/6MIbBsnzazqvei6Hw3Gd03bOXBpFCkyNlKZnUc8MQg/O@jdDdmyvR48FrwEO3K@xCjtv0OzQY4kHGkwRw/RkQd30QsOG7DSTR/SiHvslMS9OTVmItml1Jk6XxjTRzNTXt/hUiwXy3Gk27VVegQg428x/L/EGshJLnqFlNN0vPdjBA9UiyE/eJpon/fqsJrZAd6ikxhBKvP/LN9tA/5u504P6CvszA0MDNAXMKbWzMrNEUPygx/KM5d3uk75tEmHIdBvIljmCJJn9wLAcNA3tqyroGwMcqBA5DryJD9BF17AZx5yPM/rv5ZEsG6pzQG63Vvm9NsuLR0WDStBcbBMRuM5lWxSIhCzPBGvKB3ZCDXcUuLcj5U/FYsTMPN97k/GEP0EdvjUT7SHe68qm8JnKmk3dggap2bStNVk@Ms8mbVcdnnUDtTi3xO889TSyrIJWIgaZG2hcnnyewJHdheref6/yNq9fkxf0uo0rPGfiDdUmte3b/IsKwmBNDKM@f67yYouVSoFhNdXsPj0@kBMFdGAUMcciiTNY1RDR7Gtk7pvNGapCvY/nsmC@AkicSiseT6VXDFgPh6vDY/uUwheLy0NPtRanx7KehySfJavyvjlKsJg3e0uuQnVlD8y@arRDxpXCfNl0hxteg5FSCmOd4zjR@dKcm1MfK6TWpG@O5qY1LD7Hwx@cWNXPLaoNUZZbbt/2sED3V0lNf87dPC6cp0yP0LwKexkl29AQxXpcDUzLpYDbGuNc1BVs9QEyjc8BxZm2IT7R3FXEarkXeK/UIHrQGObP5ZXam6VYfYB8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@HVC9uz6LGcsGdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8jbM9u@967Jie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8f5QIRcIKV2/RUj5GpDr6OK9UrSfJUdnt2UQrf8a4cTZkHFNLbtMUolBndWpg7YBjgguT9mDVIFCakneh7giYhzLuTBn/vsXqD1WkdavPYYz0qhBwcMAxQIYxiOuZf8isWXWx9b@MKF0A2z@tkSEMvesb0F9Rc8bWcqMlP6RIfRU6sNFVKc/sSbW0rbGYfOVhcuI17QzPhyplEjGphgCwFEHXPMS@HojGocfhDVW1fi1VpiY0Gq3btdmFoXaEBTwIbaen4LhKRpuhug6k@FCri400Jyj9STrDf0i7bYXsEOXj5VDhVuUpQUV3bPoXtto4o08nHlWyaRSKaHDhIZyFj7WNabSQdhXNn8uREw285jnfnH4bhQyLo@DyBKe27hSBBmr2vbkuVhMOrZjjWf4/EBp2nTd/sfkFAjVto3aGCiXNId3XY7dUHfE6hQ2773wsM@j2VnVb8FrG9G8BPpgu3ldpofHmj4oN1UcTR3gSNfi5/oenNDI1W2x4HJu7Bbis3r7q3VJ0SGiawUtv7bUcQ3VbVp9k7@mucw6eEUtvRbeotAQo8A4aszHiudj/JFrQmk4A2LZbWio9KyBRZ9rFH2z/Wri@a@VnqYu3qucp5bVSk73rdYqD0Mb5IKDz4XB6ZCyNHYdaGKNcQIhNlX6OEVV2K6SwP5w4lIiHwzMrsX3qFgnKed9FjhNh7fs5sblvRclPjWnBcHmPcyrWQIK1Zk18/z3UoCPZy3I18ng9h63a4W/hd2gH1DaV82NvVnFOj235/SsHp@QHnytKhzAj2O@p8g61AHrbg/nyA2HC3Pnw/Tsu/3@h9ATRSMXlK7bWYrTPq6qxSVhHwV3ZjbBQbxu7b8zx1x2oGFlqelZE6iXPHfsDi2VvlZ57WNfD3@ukqH@6Pcv2om0tqkPFPHfvyj8W9uWXdMdD4f0agz7E48eFFSlxdC36U0dPueFZlu6o672xh00NWGpiQkxNOi@XMQ07XGrh4vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9Xh/@@UFtV6SMzdT7aK31bSDvaKYhv1TC7sf4OliV6aIDiVdrgWGNvrKsk47We6tD86zl8Q5RNLES9gmHSiNfFV6i5fSl1xN7PAcamiQV9PDykQk0rMJdTMtYqVnR4ou5GBbTNVZyKSnpqJCrVgoUHn1l/9LCBLpQEUun@WMVQuFUEkahCS8fQ24xqYg6CO1Q1y3YL/DXwmyopZWc05t0vZsCk/fYt0FFw8fqbguaJB3qtYY6y3TEaxWZjX4SV0/CuwE618RaO6ySXTuuQv70vmq6Nrwa8IKsm6zsQ@vbQ48/mdpZORonJklBW/z6kCGnzWx5Y1pkTNvq8FEQNN2mIg5cGqcFHURt4Zg@dqKjMOeKFxdcjtsFoa722dyz73eV2rJ0/tHy7A/qTPWLJ1bXxEncj@wxzgJdwhXEssvmLd0K@2sT07O/NoGUrWI23AqCj0SOwnsG4NcSeI/Nrt16uJARAZKCwGIKKX8tsD9a3cyLi57t4RyqwLCmYwpZjjMxcl0D2g1LfF7vug92wZgXIL6@cqnvZd3r7nCGy9BmZFrXs26PqZdVvFc1HVfNLluLxMVkMJx44rUcB5qlFe6FHpyRvXdhA3D1NYhW1jP74@U91aEuV9DCRKU4N67Sxr9h990u@0YhxUBpAyUMlfMljHMPquenODVo5CzhRIr7A0c@saNDHfGEvYa8tdJMtR17vL43ZzzGaUL@GxPDaw5c@pB8hE/t7sdCUE@WU@TR7br@fM3zLfU7cN6xOxm1LDQGG5mEmwUiVmvPn9aMS0Vc3IjlItxKWzt6A9Wh60zG6mjirK0VcmtrhRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/fqaEuYGmgd@mhVrQ@Jt4/dnctHLOwDUmsx1QxFbL0UXfflviPt936YjmIN8SZhc3h2qRuL7vLmvvPJ2NrPEHN5hA@E8G960WjhzeGvcT97HruFAbDUFQDo4svpnAwlyP5QEx2CNcLg/0ad8azTGBXVEJcW3DHFpNyN/@3PQhdREHfN8cmyuqIuobpPZfYLqVV@x@0xq9ok6/kHlVk3YRoYfWlNoWqxmGl0F13GpxlRj74xbKyMKIjTd0XYc/Sdqm4KU/Xi9VoCqgx4ePlWs4w3@hX2Bp@2wxqYfnfKKI1ea7XaxK68hqun3@XDMtybH5tABzZFte8hFunkB2uQxTQfvy1sqQ/FoZMm8agSZ7bno0Tr@8qTEHqU8/YhZQzxy1XBwJE4Y1E3RCOx7cIqaDRQN87kATCD8FiWW2JmLvxdvQ6g@aA3qsbDCEcvPIauJyoyZtEzI2pzczk/cMiT0SQpO6gp0FfHGFhTrHYk@hNaLcXm0ttKMWqWoP6UGSeuVwOc3XUR3bar0xsdfMJXrN@6YX3CHNySdkXNFXHSpG1IucNGkJ/dKStDh7DRSavqWOeyNo8yfH67q3/f1bloyHTAYWDjIvjsKsVF1dr0eJdZePpwfCdWSpYu9AkCXBPoJcP1R3V2qeCB7@h/e@moRKuJHL@HuagOi6fQQfkJ@MHPH6EA586nrjjj09BLxx3cEqcYLJykIQePGSgaatVYmA3HMmfd770A1NvRq0qTmm0v61qtoncT22VMs5V2mHuenNFLl8NVlyFzdDHVttVWywgCMN6iN/YVngTbyXDKCGZSPO99STnLDTXEbMAF1G3AtfMoC@5Y7VoUfv5NB7evDo8EQbevrS@mm3h@sxbuhxCzs2GIVUqEvqlTkKjXfyGWlt2xsn7x3r6t6jAw09rKA3H9FQ4YUjcwuvlf2eYutRM2mubAWhqzVeriA@PHn8KD5f@8lie72RO7CUsPPe8XEC17Z89Xipczj0AygdHXe6MvjBvq4rS9j3mUOjg6uk55KYVkE6saA1Csz4kG/4cqty1XKHVvtkNrQ@h8oTJbj3gdHnVibyiXlud7EUsuJKQlFBZUUtl1FCk7OhsW2Ngveq/DyzhygtW/RK8tfK6SioOaSTo/Ry7WHdiP91LYalxEyEjwukp25y69hWoWR0e2hKmt7fFzFd11fR@djsQL6y7MrMWvSwbHy4755/wFCyJRovamCljoGrVPvWqeR5dQCiO4kP7J4XlmBsrpwGsw5AYJ1bWuAvLGdmOiqNZa1TL0oQGie1rfXyDesDBqSCGT7nuCH00jG@YFY9i7XIqNwS8ckoFGRv797BbQGOBC3X@/r0yTP21PRwd5P1HsMYWx@A8VwzeqVivxVurbdyOLU9AlDGWnjd4fLyXGLH5qjtOrPp7YNwtLgVq3barDiAhV/kyerbU3tZXdXi/VpPl08zui1uvo7DnS3oweFdbwSg99/5Z7qeStGeRvjWU/zzlpzxCziLocmc4UZ5YaeTg0A0tFBv0cBCWdoafWRNcToK7w1e1qhfWr/l1tR9eWV1dbLOrbDGLbMmPu7G1xEdTZzwzrZeQuxNwJf/8QVZnuZvPxyLOfG4oizucB9efsYXXuH@Z3zNFPh9@5ZtiKVR4BCsFhMLsnCbJNDTLFzGKBEIXCcXcyoVPVtkO7jPfAmksEIxglWJ70bjR1Zjm5dioVOppF/hYi@5JDOxEC3YXJJvkAiAcWs3SBRTz3S2OQaXTX@ZFKMtvtlbRqod1CV6NgVfWjK8brUs1o8BTpuXTw@e7h@f7J48O66l6leyIlZJctwcB2Lz189@km7LkHhBN2AZvl0qrbPsQ3S0/TiqhJ6fLgYpu5a0ykLS5omSdzDM5qXjJJO0XDCpXgF@qsxjI1eQ/2jFYfsppgwSqz1LfJVdn0gqb3LQMsUJmVZiqWURD03Pg2QJ9@sHIJArS6fRlUcsdriEgtp13baI0bPY7Zcf44Pdg0fPjvaZj@Ccay7s9rhXKWb5BqgoVlUL8qlj08yDCouKIFHIq0ol@iAKhIlqUVaiRZq0@SgwOnjzqYPLO0XoLRbbJPhAwWiQKcn/8s3kVVTDSXQK@I36SEWZoDx6YCe48OrPftLmm3P72y34p3yMBiRDaFm7JBZVrlhSiRSlkjlcfdYHbYZNqyeDXbjn56dItDc7cOUF7ZR0bRcdhTa24Ae3iE2O/IiIQfwNfbE3BjcsgqbkuY1LJzkOHdw/aJGVcQCX9szS2C4eZAI8z0zaIB5QnzhjvkeHWNEfAT7SAomSYJuELN9OXg55jG5vACs3ra7tMM8BFdcal9gr4DPs8Sjx9buqWo3eCOKD5ifYqL3xoB/yeGPDIS95Ok6@/7XvJrtlBuZp6h58/Yr46oD5V7n5RRLz@uamRPP4w0jgRmICax55QHOkd@jMFoevk54TC/dO8kUlsweQNedEafTOY@BPFSTsHE6s9jlkFLAY5JJYH83js0b1GO5kVkomkY1w9EijOaHWlE/QuLajWS6by@hJQFI99wHSFsRdXHzGASpKCRhfOreHlZdNYK/tbSajxmRVcmWem8lN50Vafhkgugl@pYseIldjEAaCzEOAW1UEg/okrisYFOVRVI@iKGq7UNGQO1ZI@O0IQsgsBsTiNLJwT9spHt4zHs38nfmaeCBOaHv6TQFI1aGaIZMiS2JJ7xN3DCyzsJiZL@nFCUq8UsMtrzx@OBVtiIc8qN0sTfOVaP4@@KJ8aVjuOah06nr9GM5b@TmCOEYQJXkZy9ZesNPxqVNPct5kwKY/EiwbZmYHzP8k2V3Bszzduze3Q4td38wMicXuHjsuqoYPIDEsZiSNdFLPKfMkZTJLkyRSJKKB5OAmDW8hOhBNICZalv3KHXq7e/sHXz18enxjyy/yGb3uDSR5dTt@qmqJWj0wRMPJWsySew@Sx4/vPfAzYo50LiSBQX0RKdHXpWTe4kOQ8xnE15O2DMPrqVuN8XO@zPA6vmljHWoU6AYeeuoj4qVZfOoDmot/PXKjsIxa2ew6lObwkiHQe3wh1Q1UY8rlVa2@XT11ItGbnLCkILyIaFtYCMB06m1tJpHZbyYOExYcIneCx9944bKYXl4W5c007jyDSznH7tl8zx1hEXIIpdePBkSkpCV9rytL3yFXu@c7Qxn8kDu@R014Z44QwrnUOoqHQJ345@WhFJnvaye2dOtBu6tvNyV/RxS@tZu/A1WwqxvfzSSmSGJ3dB5xTJygNy1NNRqyjyko7QhWgq3bJc6Hp0hQoFFfezqB9t9Td8h3y6WhmfuWbzpyQfzen/AxXot9dTIAfx16HVnUTQaSW4XAQMlogCrXn0BKiE3ipnHchg/iq@FWcSLh2qCdjU0VrWdN23YXZHtMSYBE@0TX6yzYSA4TTRvHOVGZ8myeC2uL4qe4PC5M9o/aTXA6R8CsmZrttK1pLHoRVUp1iB/toxfPz6OKvIyXaFdDsc1f@/r2hgH6eX29JDHHonT6ewcukxbF4k0pAXbXAfN9efyjOopFredJdOJSBXXx4/HoERhBjYh1BuaQxSYO37tIY/QZO405CdrsRa3y7c8cFo9TEwle5KAxCtkhE6@/Y6YzY7FkBZgAbT2nja839pDVdE2rg5kiUdgmHqGzBxoX7gOiSNCshSAlAltBFoKGA2DEC4nGGRzCoLuE27OMaAeoJc50ogj1JrhIE0o1q95hoZOQFjVHuVgsiQxdlIpFBtx3UxxqSQB7Q875ujxQV@wzADSDBq0mReaC/KbEi1C8EY7IQ7FBAaATCW1Z6O9bwADWfEPBVm@Ed2zfgbKCW62Unp08aBSUpMyCjQ66I7uNvV18192g0SbOSYBimlzwGi3zNtqnGAx3sGrwnRRwg6UHVGDkayI1EibD9XNB57yp62u5XgQUuQA@M1gBiNUgDR8cbtXmjzsucVsu7H/@czx5VI5t7uTSjf55PJpNleGhl7Msyz7ZPFXVzZqRTVXubtZNc3wqMzOZ2bp/bvU6zYNu8lSWWZplksktI/f6bKjntl7UtNfTulwrVBJn9adn7OnTL9413iny9Hwmn8ZYPsL2Dt/KOiQgUsqzIsN76UVHAi691rTS5SjAPT3FE0XlvJxM1qJ1@JPTS7i4p1pVq2o79XfvlFoe0jSdnUbwoD52eJecqZ1EXU2GoRzbtp1kp0Ov3Ybb7bE6P2o2wq94PKYyYaHWuB0bTDtkN921ut3Jvjnj9nZkgq8HYxH28TeeP3@Ohud0sTdHIjyHzvw4Sg0zG2FGyvizn25cJS6fNrb/7FuDpLWBr0N8fffqMZqP9ewnGxuf3LuXySSAStz89BtPv767u5u5n8g@rWV3MmpqY/tP/2RjwzC2jeRG3fP0erR2dvaFbKQysvZnP442nj79mudhtuCVZjoY8VmAW0ed6oy9geusw/BP5jftkNlEc7PzhhmRNxFg68iMfo0I46WwQlpS@NpgenUn/1@/f/g6Mo5UjeTzEbzHkdeRXCHCjWCAr7T/dR6pRrbRW@4qMktWKhUw5v/rv4Pw1a8CHHSZbcOjmvVh5WaRqlqhIG8j1RwYdMOAeP@vb37zlm6fu6wGl5zJG/JOHa4turYl3F5KTSWT17zrhTv6HcaccW9sufiy@cuBFzPLDrS6j2rxeLyuqXBpDQqU1HXjlDpswqxF/S2RwLrMuA0L2c35RNiA2/MI8RQwFfEVNwsLYjVu8fy6v@dLrvLzf@jrSIrkNu5a96tVEIVG1diqxunaOC2VOPmTLF@QXfcu9mhFT@Uoe8keCWJX5VTBkBOJxN0GnuPMpkhTdRqZE5BxGrHIAmUjbP7FwlYR5gdjcz8f628frz//3/78B3/@ffr9gO7/iDtxOW27k9ziyJ9X@cWqVbk6ki9P6eMuS5UKpUKywa5OY1u1av2I6alP30az6egxppE8sVPF7@GMBFe1ig8fDfyqRrhNlZvmdsKlGnyQj3mQ5f6YkEw@USNQBYsJS2rtvM5x4/jdvGp3IZtkI1@U61UjaxxC1ukyZVyR9TY95kZEinbg2oAf/eHawc5jYYPPDbLkLuR1ybURoHL7tYClFKnVknWrDoosq/pA7m6UNgqlXMmATFkNuLwKdOQ8LE20vFbQDBAf72ob7Ijzep3F/es0fuv1TNMawkgGF29VdacRKfIPcFUlFrmEq/5uq/YOWFdEXRPlNL6t1qtxgRG8tMbdely9uqppL@LlsvhvVwNjmS5ugoTUr1R1@wXAqt2EyoHSU2u82Aaw8e3adsXdo1trIInV@otqbXsxrAh@924cZexdAFDdrLNoxo3m3LtMicc3VXWjtjINALgeAyVgGzLwavuqelXbvrra3ob/Nj2vxBtsr7Zv/Ok1v1b4mbtTsTmtJaunyVPBNnX41pJVtNGSp2Cowhv8QTUkRUAxmUqRLbYVGTI9nwYTs0r6lpFOZqef5PZBNarVVWzBVNSansvWVS6pXmqspPLtu/VCTtFQFDXcTgNX3GnspRR5@f7L/wXv0/df/j7W@1Asi1IkuYXNgyJvJcDjscMeP36M92PHgT/cj/nloA1aPEY7hz8c7sP3E1hzGywOIBSYbBRyciOuzwwW2ZZzeRQLv3Tjikaj/@ilUcxHeQsaV6a99MDyl5Zd/@iXVl1S5G0Ry3nLYzxNUoTKPeQFlJ8qGi/x0XyNv0dv8Pd6jL@TFv6OXuOPnbzB39EYf@xxE39PPfydvMbfbhN/JwP83XuNv8dj/D3r4k@KVEDb3txJ9VOtlH6mn4HBZqkRS/VSPb2NTYGUxVKz1IylBq7eBpMFvxSY7FSHpbos5aQcXQdHMIxZaoymDry68OsAlBH8bBycPtNTLQax9AEoP4KH3m9BkimnUg3akPJLC/RiTddSWs6u48blNbluFAtMQxJrjdrL02gdd8Q0ihnWnFkbpy9ZxAOduhxJnp4mee8AMzJl3OP86qrR2H9yv9FIoiw6fewezv@Hh4Pw59r/4NB9fOgOXPgfHh4@ZlY1fjeu3oWrUo1vi9dOpFreOS2pWHB9WRFJbu@cVtMqmnNxKP4G2sU/8ppDhHd141SKMlBVLsqkEJUvzssXZTIEn2BolAMPwhs3gGVZKFJgU/Y1qgu4zi/IEh9ovHh@Gpi4Ifn84hQbBtDiC/6gcYY//xv87f93/R8/Y7FaHRSc2OXVdowuBX@Kcnl1eSWeVSUWEx@xbfihBXxjkMurKhrJ0yWYajGlrlxdcTt4xpRtDrCKcWxXKfDcI5T@SBAnxcsfsf@2b4xbXKe4d7Y5H6o/PZ2mUkq56e/Vi8NU5lsaMVXKdPLKZrOm1//0x7Qj845CnrKZclnfYvzDyBjlcsb/yhfK5YL/sRmLFW9e1dSOngMNJ5NRlHIZPnZ8sCn4DMAWAKz/kQWolme2qNyXI5cHh7RXMYiJbETBFHHBEEvRluZ4OkZULsl37sTEqZs7u8qdO0Yx9fZtYDMcgpW@YNVotO1Ro4H26bdv5YZMQ@fFLHynCm/fgiyLKu4o9gQPVYGIYqrOPjGqFGfRHQEh8uDM9KQxx6JneuZ4PIq9sYcJGafZeLJCZx6kUu7oNPqz733rW6fRSkVWZbLN6AgAY2HZ7e1cplrNZcCcKwCl5M1LfvxHN17UlavNpMypweTNaEQ46YW8wmVjFN2himM7VSjgHl7s8ipC2c4yWSUG0lUBTesqgj9urReL3J5lcrFCvCh@lQ2FVUEJ4D9soKbjma381t06o9902YUiuXxpVfSryqVVwn6@q3JLnGiH6/KsO3fSRaBpIVU@lRqN@7snu41GRZZlrA/hgZYk3CU8SGc4itYow7PFeg3TVz@NRkvlu8QceiHLItGy8KdGoZZghSKRQbI7uOgW0i7povW/IRn0xockOoM2wBIPnWfz@@mj3b39k4SxDTqN8WB3L2EcP7sX0fEzO/8m5zR@H@3v3j98BgGePtrfPd7/9ODz/WdPwd5jF/PLl8DiOX@HTUu@L9hz6dXojWlZpjWxrMbFZHLxmr2y7YYNhO1PbNt2uyPmWQ3Lsobgzb/KcLdsz3z1yhwN6WLvf/Sd9z/6797/zvfe/8533v/OD3725Q@@A/dP4P4ef3/v3xaz@PzZl//sd9//9u@A5X@E@4/g/unPvvzNb/Kbvv8Y7v8csvtjcYf88VsCWL/ysy@//@OfffmrP4T7X4r7hzfvX/vp8vsH3159Y7jv/@56P9/7d3D/Hofl@/3eb3M7fN/w/9vc36/@8P1v/Hv@/1PxQ@PvvP@NP8aH@PinP/zT//z@W//BMAp/@m/ef/v777/9rfff/u77b/9j4/1v/hs9FX787vsf/MFf/eHv/dUf/k/0/wk9f@9D/u9/@E//4n/9i//9L/5Q3D@F@9@D6ad/8R@AYf/2D36E/@//wd/@0Y/w/z//q7/9g1//21/512T4LW74v//lv@XPv/61//Q3/@K7f/XTb/7Nr//0b37rD/7q//jV//M3/9Nf//e//9f/47fQ8rd@@ld/9Ct/@a3v/OW3//lffuvLFc/vrH1@@QH2X/4D2Hw4nh8C50PS9bE2X/5C@Px9qDGPBfgEuPufvP/NXwYG/w3G3n/nJzi7FO4V/58YOvn5Cf/6/4DBuJlmdEmBCe5ff/@d7yGJ/gcgEfwDen03@Fhw4R/fnX8AWf/FtUARq7RYeRaMQnwLWhhbxaKoQAPnbQr5sy//@Y@DKH55EeqCG8T4XZRUC27fRRn3/kfffP/jf/z@R7/1/ke/grWZmikmdhOqvr73GapANfsB/tBj7kP8gccvvoD4p3HqK1Xj@MW@EI5ffPGFNH2bxOnMd9@C7RdkxS/GncCNCSffTdjjVNWwH25M@cZNtH4bjhrJEMdo46QKbPl6SjbNpnGB0RS74vAN9uBpukXGKT7JFp2nEj7m/7lxKrE4@uEXngDjG8kgwokouFHKQjTx6dSnFylOjCsrvOd2SsNIFG@myDAF02l8Ci1SMEAMcXC6F2eVSiWOASscH/jkqFULjFCJxyuQbgzNwyQaBQQxvUdQIGQlfsQaW5UpDxhHeFWfHHEJrY5k3ZDjhcp9iLAyvc8QFgInsC9fVqqFyrSK4N5xesSn8XuEEwKrxKfVd/BdIZhx7FW6/w5QKVTi8WoBI8RE8uxJNHgmZSlxlPY4i4s8gDd10d5l7BNZL8h8SGMDCcZ94zM@971Dg2w74H4a3xLJob9vpHuLCL5BUYlYGHffIVVxh2uP6AHgqqqmaQxuHLjbYXfBecpBxSlaeMU5hDhxBHFAYAFsiHkRp/yN0wfEH6lsffQVr0o8NZubm1KkKqflQxriiUOrfXRW4kd4vOVNoxKTc0UZrS2a@s1TZ20@pW6Hrftb8NThv79BM7LjrExobUaxdy/KeHzskzi/797dYp9A6uk9t5OYGk@7Gexdx4Rux@OyAbFW3bj0AqSbBOxLgN5K2rRCA0txKZFgTKtE0I0dHh4K1MjiRUWKA/cbaR2/cSRgMplEIISmJbREQrw1epOFJgwauYq3tok0p95IZhiZMrRvygytWLg5okO7FS3fvXsHmUWzMkoH0KJkYoKGkSmQI1jwVZ79/sxfOWBkihJvTjM9xw/ZjtEZfApTJBZjW4rE5@9yJPwrFjUKhSiaFMgTLbblz9fJ6ZLfSUh9hEEI3sYrZBXfce@Q7R0@frz/5GRYrzPJosMRrcZw5LYsz1snmGMYbvfJfT693yjmEI1IrYYxn5QMFEvSfilFQvPg/tHBcYlxmogcigWQlDJ1AAtSFHUpMhw@346IOQ0yntbhysf4LM3THzOKaYywWpYiLQubJcBw@Gdl6bHXvedOoS2fkOWEnsMmmkJdqEz6ulsqVd7pmbwEb/qeMNxXii9ChdKJk8C17W0imlS9VKnbG42QwTmpWhWTg5guVY/3TyDAySHTjZTGoKV/mckbmWwma6RzuWze0DO5YiaXLaShrsmlsoahFzOZYqGYv5KqX7CphriqYO5X@pbTHfc2cUqOfJqSQ/TYrKUS@DPSaXgCxISezdc3NvqXKiJ4SmxxiXOrruDzUkUKfAUuJn1FYl8BK7ggDpwwxcRstYPDspgyhNs9xPi8IVnPQuFWpFNgJA5OGoav8nAI5Qda@6Fbimx84xtjVq1CK1s9eCBFQEz1mD9vRrXbWk8jRmpPRha5dhlr25/beIiL1ra9Yd@cQeFMaVLk6uqqA5AOHuCgKn3yEG18XrXIpgnmq6kp/f/XL3xFVLUqbQ@rwJLbySEYTTBmtpMmGJtgzG4nm2C0wVjcTtpQPUjbfI8khkswK/LYmuKWbNxOrnpWv6PhwoCKTFANeVvsOVgV4aq4wsI12xVcp4cz42PKpdSutN0WnRcltbWm255p3njWxxn0fXdUiYIWFvUdbDyCExdkVWqsrg3dIdSVRjYfr@kpEM1464WEkcgm2jj/fmiOcX3FTjZVurCdtnuhffH40cPxeHhk0cz8nUyxVKjXarIcrxG0Op4yx4ufurEBHGuZbRXeHdcZe6pRqJfSqYJ0FaRKAnogqlUJfcYRxQTS5FKwc8lxHetq6zJOSSl1Op0rybxU@Rek62qLxc1E8zKwKKshn1txe@5yJZXMDlQUly0@pa4kG9mCXK6V59/5nFyuX0l3B1bbNnF@/Wnq8kagXEq@CvycptDbEk859ATJ5IkDxuB7QVVpIlgNJFd9HyqkWn3b3yUKecMwVCOtpnVVT@P/FoOB/w/3b8DfwCeEShvSCa6UfAICDCS0wx7hptRjl524Lp0/ds9qrfCx1zNpxtveyPW8v4efe6Zzxp3u23x7osDpoYkHD3gDe9xb4ePZcICLLK3RPxiE/UETEKQiRR7uwWPUd91lHvLs2dMVqXwcbAgIxOA7AoL3o4NPH56E3if7u3sPpRy7d/jk/rVXVnjKskf7D06Czzx39YNmAxBf33/06PqneEWwLsc@2Q2WzfsGXcIps3egJXNHGLO5uTGFxud8NZftBVM4@bK9knTiL/EyGZbnpsVafN0rNq1oTwqhYen5oiQNmeNesHyKtd1@38SzFzsbYNkzcemKhTpDn44Ixagv3FG/fWG3rQ3pMa6SKep4wBwiIT0EIINJixaA22MJdzhq46mIOAbQxIPdJ3jy6ApLeKEVGkd2twdi@ML1PUhN02Rwf@wF4a3wNV5vMeZxkN0Nl/5N71JEQtXQHJuRQvnOHf3pCDi7WkiVSl0LGg9D16vuT4G72IQ9A343RyhEN5NsMyvnWvIDpjUi5haoY1275nr14RErYM90y0xntkA71lHBAJXQtPIRFLygELFEgaFyhIprzQDl6DSVNDMuaDGy7JTfsFbZHVa9aOrKurJe5/LxnQwIfahNQMUrl/76X/wEeXwrCeIsossyTu7d0CWNdFGjWMgWimmjkCgUC5msnstmE7qRAFU/X4QIU3pBzxWyRT1RyBTTGVDuwDVbzEsRPnMquUUg4V0CsE4Lz0zbJnVW61WlCB80Ym9ipsIiZvA9YbIFYWQ8Jdsb0@rBLbsiGxmmpxi0ZACiyVos8uDBXurBA1m@hx84VL6XkuU2fmQLqVT@nixb5LJXwHpZdnmYAm49IY/5Ryp1b0@WJxwA7tooyz382M9hR4gs2/ixt/vgAcbTwQ8Dw4O3M@7CP/r@Rx68OfiRTlNPiiy/DsCBv10eUYYw3ccPjBNdHnCXPXCT5U99fFIpgHDE/XEID/207u7K8gH/2N1Flz1KeJaj@hl@7NIly8A7WH5kuQuG7ghKriw3wYilSJZbYGrNTLDDE@pwaz9nbMryjBMISSTLU/Jtts5kueHbYzQPHz40e@O21eXXbMTfLUANXOzpZP9B89NPm91uczTb3f/0CF329h6andlk1Ow2RbBmAy4XwoDL2WB2/QIcDxoNs7/U5TNwca65NGYNC3FrmK8BJ3F1MZJBYw9c9sBl2XgbhwbXALw28bo3gPc9s0ku/kUu9J42m3IZGRVVQzpmFsoMnfiaGJitkVvG72llg7FoLJqY1XKpepkc2ACUwFT5is6XjeHTxJa3cjmrTSupemVayRt8okYnJp9OjawtJzYGO3oxW9owd3QjE5@WcA2x24myqKrvsJh@Z@sNiz1Rdox0piSf7uyock2v7xh6oZTLv9iayLJSwudOOl8Cj6kotEvxodTy9Z18NhQkn4@bSaOUzyvlKyDHGGrZJgqWRix2YZlnioLoYvsJksBPt51ROu1yJzZNTCscLzZTytOKXua7TrHUDVht3OJw0hq7Iw6xC@CmO6kSnZ8r68WCDPEnkzFFAclEQgTe83lYz792cnZy8gXILGiZinbdU34oY1l8fvpwT4OmnvjCrQm1B6iCuyNtDwXLggvfOc@3OgG5qj2EqhK0dN8O13WM3L62P4XWNurxvoO/4ZQmtgnSTh4uwDmGRi2PGZfFlmmvCadlMdy50W4zs1IFk9lmMcKKmcoFVdKNarXSqAz4EbjVINRnjLY1nIM58DjuwWJdCn6Jax2EQ6OSuio3K9PIFOA0KkzVXw7c9ksj3iq3ccPGe5V7GLjcgHezbFUsPAhYjsjlzo5TYWzieGbHemqNcOn5weEm1ES4ACLWYZayyU7p2OA91Kmv1OqIOXPMnkwGMVOtNpVFq9Ankib2NT/Jl7QiB0ewr8qdCou9UMqv4XO0yWJt7Z6ykym3Y/dYQwGb1MvOyw4zWC5TppPUYggJChHRho7jVSrVz0DL4YDPSiVAROTxGcDEmACs3SYHUxnaV@VWpc9iKpsyhciTKXcrNQz9Fh/bqizXVbX2ti5VVfW5VIVyWp5FzIo3adIuvyzV1I1UrjwFOz2fKfcgY80X0/KoMoTGf7kPn6KTgy88MstATqAagHnzNvb@l7@pbKvZCrcrE6i3fVAsGlqjMi07uG8IsEQlXQGHeC2TSmQLUONn8wmokA1QAXKJdCKTUPNoC7UxNAfBUgdVINaPyYzJidQ0pekJ3dITUPpf2u2XTEmcxUAnIZLBx9jdx1OIwQYyCbmSPuFtMiVubPUZ5ILLzG2V2BQkRRkTBjTvsaGd6CGoI8vsUwhFUVl6K9bfjKGfzZPJcL9WL5X2p8OvgVNMfb2Ti@dT8TeKUo5tKBXPei1Vy1IVpQqlergBPCv6f5g3GdQgj8ebet4o1WpNTGE@lUin0pA8u/G2uy1X5XoitZHTIYeuGOkxjAsMrsvMtZG5XQM1azzSm@lFoyxpNNWBYtRjRnHVihVFwkl2AqA0FMIOKcxip7K/9C4WjeaNaFSJlrGneEMWHXwg4fjp4CBqo3f0HRn0J7kkFw30MBeUtLoqFVahriRsXLNMUYpcSleXV9vQ9EzSnDdQFdkGmVSteleKlBgDPe5U7N@R3GDsY6fSxberL/j7FGfbAlyJ9v0CdZEmuFg2tpfY57iSdIdFATFzNKgZRrpeM/JQv4HM9L0ahl7GfvAITuvVqkB57xLw245XcRHGZ2w2M@OqT9k7jHXjmxIlOnKd7LuV3e7Rbtn/2sOeuFNJluVyVI5cRiPRK/hJkbu08sPgKz9YJLT2g88WbVlAn3cRkhhs79LvkCnh6RMxs8TlQ62uvHti9y8LaZW3/UFgXV1FNpOUI2ICffmzl0YW8shx/Rn10AZCbRyqrmwW@xEjyZdD7xtGIf344NC5P3pgMT6hvpBpyNUIS@kqzk8vl4Rtlk@olYsFQzbOEhF2N1KOsDM1qpdo0j0bHhdf5F8UXjx@dvjs8IEUOd14u@FiHzPzycLeOV/9GniMpjNRxk4rkWklUxZzmqpVVd82cGucPMMj3jt6Tk29rXL2rZJDzgCX97/8w8x0uwDfBmivJcjCbNyoVvUtgymR4fsvfx@3RLjc/3z3EYt65oz93Z/82Mj/3Z/8K5opFL0qe9SfmY@ATzTquXzk8nJ4eXkFF3fLRuoRjlQmr4CZd57rkfm8/lLSNLfy8Yxx1yknhV89rysRT42IIYJ8NuK9FU5GqgBOfh8@Wck5zILI/pGdNfS728gUerAciM2Hii2vCFxRePzyLWPw0aq2u13bIFMyyUrvVLb9Tt1m77AP/J26wV5Wqjhuq@MiIr/Td6tarSIUFq3Gk1tRZmTBrXZVrscZ9RtDg/CFteVsnS5y9OkGKxYdsLe8LTHKcLrlQatvy6GfteV58Ol/WVuvPCbjOEgy2W7TXjHbFstWIf@3koDOqfL@l3/TMHJ/9ye/9rbxtvGFAS23YjGnG5Gf6z//OXhYs3rdb3ZRnzguM0dD0FxjK44j1lrQUsQzqjuM@/cbb9hcQ53B7jrQZscv6Rz1HMqaBt8SqR0jb1u4uDVBWjNtWKKUJSnQLkkrHnVbCYLBtnCreCib0qX0FXSCypRVQFxKX5mDAosBVJ9uq@H1J6MhTZaPUTi9nmB3IAjE8BXcbmqDFuUKmauCmEpu3QzKUfaIaqQTsYHlebh5FdQi0lcgiNjWC0/ANXH9OPq0HRDyGnohPMmhXYO46xB3nwdokG2MUs89JBjHjgdyQHOWvgLKAFHBBh2B2dvgoQyC5StAAEhDTAC262ybpRV2acfj5fnOWFc47xi3NjP9tasSBkNobVwr7Qcuoz@wAo0dD5JBvhA5DOpZyNIHwmHwcdEK6PwYnL5Q6aLF5R8MCmDRRi4xShq7c2eOVaVitxVGKUL4Z/YQe6YoH5zluAIwv730SbskJxjuOVb2bQO2A4rHCV3gOpVvNlYOBWUyfl5JEvw/mGmRI69lFTmUMQEiv3ipaAHJIDCSnedhi21XmG7kFRYg3wLcW4QUbXMVNAJPp59oxhe@4xVg@POIv00zSJ@TcG@f4Nvri5cZVHsT3CMXt7DhwkAsOuab1KAUOxj7oYNQkBS7T7479ggaKDQu6@94FUvrCgab7xBGeNBMYiPDcEpvVsEXhULfDN4m7u0k4tmg/SlaLmSoN3Qd2gyKNq7A2dLAESCjxJ46HO2Jc4F7qou8ocBhjDzaTwc5HzGmza3oMDoKiwOdzRG0Yn3aJJjV1Vhr0GZGkcWI0WjvHycAp1AgQrgJ2i7SuNm3BoDSsWUx3A/JKyWTXdCKJk3aAOmxDXzVe2BDVeJ4SXHuX/LCPrOTJ7gnrOp2QIUWy8kjqEhh8eNjqmKzob7rnrG@fWbxTtzYwmJ8j4G@D0prAig7v4GwJewvNtIJlgLnBPcFdx5eeW4sJEJhN2Iz5eY7rW/EGpijb6lOskd4pt@56YToS9dbSTRxvZnnb@dBm1LAtxaIXEss5K9EcQ1xsEOFJDYmqdCeGBp25A9j0OD0N/RAI@ji1jnDxqqEdQwIzZa/NB5LMaT2K1QBUNmDkoV7e41HJdzQATAZtWMtKHpCwDvsE5Y2JPTId1sRO6MADMz6yiJ0cIOgmA5v3IaM0fgyLJArUDoHbXDDpcSC/TC8z91opn3X5uzNNgQ4rHQorgrjxcL/yIY@sHQgP1PSN8AxBxguwWQjJscBbFxWZA46CH89OOd2iWRJid2ElGAIQZAaoJCq4B/6yUKbn0vgcM/0@A6ZYhewi4sLjbajm4xszfJwQ3APTzJNDrs26MRucmwNhuLoJRuP3BNw5yaVnwOA59vuTOlk2eKdGX9LUseriBkQsWjHi2LleI77XXcHtI0N7h/jEUM9sGmv/FZMTNrg/GfUE5c@/5WQ/9RC9AqBMIZgpolZopUAYIlm6yzRuWiXhcM5FUgADrlo@Za4BeTI/xh4vskedgIf7pjWJvjfzf4ZDWQCJJl3nc6j5in0fc78T/E9tKcQyLEu2O5oZM5i5K6gb2Tg2IzUHjaDap9cwAjVDLvk@xHa09qsvhB8GgSHSs1v8rAR7lEjXa4HyjenRPcpd5@C@5S7T@eR@tHWpnWukqHVFSYHuR63NvN9IpiZ7@eKb@Q4dyHIoFgznYNAn7MFuyu4WxUK7dObf0E@VnzGAJ4YAsGtWLL24rR2Wnc862KrHk92gdllIgTkOICu1YmmF@3AjNTvn/eHrrdg5eCOdlArCbzRqtUT3MB5BdMYZBAxBqeXjZuQdQdifJ0rBCLBAAH1MHBE1WB3HLOVcrAbKjkC49TkOY05YjWBTJ20L@Ek7EBd4qTnhA0DqocAoX2QJEATXJhfcvjxD750eD7CU659vyrtWD/AzXCi9ShQ8lpR4bKmTJkUwkpVfTSB7KiuVq4nxXeHrKhdcwol80rkfxj9jY9GvwPlYjn2xLC8wihL4aKCU8JAhRDFhajKqpVQvgIGyS2zb42g5trn@qmorSGaraTfzODxYBK8CzzTMhbK/JbC84dWi8mOXApYYVapQBJnFV4sebnwScoJHgTzRLCZzwgiPBcgACO1NJglgk3DwaaVChccbLoi2EUIySkhOeVBuO/pCiTrIhi0noLDkDF76qCd4gQ0GeDpvBoFNWgoMzzYEserX@FGXThKKeKcyxziAsFDqGIjn7XqS2OvhZAOCa1rAJARbwBo85OkStJ1gaerwVcgozgpfRnFvwQbcFkBDEYiuMw3s4wFTEZtYFD45TjVA1B25XhNknXq18Vfit9ywrf0b/2mZWrRp75omUpc@/2DWNaRsqECGtI@9FQGBTK2ZJ6JI8AXdI4IHrrYc0Gra164LLZE2Qb7pH96eLLZd5vJgYlzRPB8meBMccVvP@CYCLs7dMfm2M1kSrzRZBPbLYuftxnsruNC0yS8iS3oem3X8pzoGDK15XYd27MSeIo5V9ktmrHAdxKXwnqyMLqeJIk@SN6MRdCcr1DVbTTwxLtGI4Zzy5RSMHeVppohe0ajErZ/wRQKD@JJAD0cxtzmK6s1Vm6Hifsti2AndussdjgUjlGIZJeBDGuB/g@uPdBgmOfOW4608yuq0s1xjPar77kDtwta38TTJAx9DfzBHDYiZA6HhEuCmdikLYV23aZSEmslTEUE/eyjg7LPjJipBOGNRQALxEiw0XUaI2VHS6JrrIyOB/PjO/54fI/D@B6vx5da4ddx5k3zCnf8uKjTsTkE8DhHI307Gph0kFvtG@gsoBJYo17FA3wwim2ag9VGTHfB667wrnWAPxLBlwdfAeKfr6L/@gz0g@9/aPaZeAzo8QzkzQCnBsboJAHPH9yMgfcDRZEiS6ILWPv@B8YFfvEQlweoQoAaS4LLwU0roWAOodntBVup@4Bv4XmcSnWD72l@VYU7LsFpdJ5gZ8bqLLrfaFt9c2a1Y8JnIgTXT/ERNNhIXn1YwlHQkdBzeVsvBnWXErhCNY5E555KK1jGTJwrymq24l7sgHuop5wwPFhNP3S/IZqxi6/Ce6uhHRCN4gZqzrmN3Z/D2XDG90Xu8wMghBzl9Q/PSVwTfztBgA5iW5jEPFplnfg8igVJ@oAaIfCrLSYZty31IeKOoDfz8ONIdHtKIXNDgSp@LkuLe/wvz3F7XY6HuMLnST5u9GEseRvTfTDPhViNA5uLsL2Pq0JuQMb5GK1WLAyR26zNMde5IRPQjvrpnBW1SmOJQA1CkqQb29TcJv1CkbBlfABv7HD6HN4IsGuNG5yh/LRhn5Y4mYWRy8AchrQWYQNKOkAJUZGTXKAR8iX5ZvB@eRXE2VoZZ@tGnK2FOIMSsBhlyJPUWohS5AJmz7os6Fud8QrpjE7YdobXOrENl@OaI@ytuIza0ZKdYNHzaAkEctSKlvZjIJSj7WjpPhm8aOmYDGfR0mdgmJet6NtoyS8W6GEEn2S4i/ZChON3K1raiylX0tg8szw/Xi1aCvIU/OzwT6IIkALTDVojDrE5rkjmeGRBxUZKZYIhx3gJbD5RP0yC7hT8@akdtPs/OmIf5xZ5ZnGmL1QaoRqDxwPVhr@79JKSXBK1@f7hA5rPFHjBaOLQxguHIfCghkeii8KII4auNKIBb0AQ5WZpOUYsVJN9IDoiduBQyuTF@Il6GukD7Ri518BzfR4JHdUiwvv5tQiCZ@CH4YmBV@F5Ax0/OsIIx2SVJWghUV9G1yQK83oRF5H74Ryivu5FT3iOru@F5xKBDcl00OFocA4jG7rDRSYhV5wdb4fDUKccL5TIvdeCkVQQJXOFM1mLlKFgCBd@ZV1yQuEQtQURhI61VJ2XsqBeIFmMTnNZF9JUeeEDFEIyB0q41TqjY3DuCyP54@ImQXXFqmrID8ujJMm1KCYhsIab@0zMMY89aLzu45Y/H9d89UNOsa8lhgBCIYNYuHx1P0J/d7n@7ivUPhGuRbBMsV5eld5Ur9fWstcw78@jvZmB6Jhg95WlylEQw5zk0DoIaebreO2Gio9TPriSzyMNoF/T9n2yBW2CW@h2vW3BYaGWMDpftDwzwPLMWE2omxpJ/1zzlRYNYxJweMIDTOdJW48rT/iyLEYX6t82@x@dwaPFDA5nHsKjBIyukZyX8tHEoVku87INYpvboEjVS4wLchouDbJ5bgninoZug2FbsDhsHN0/fPLo61Dp5vN5RdTRszl@WGqxrzWoxzlkmhwd1AdLmi1GAk@2wMFu7I6nM6s3Th35hizhwhqUARNi8dlPlHFFyLKQPL9WdiEc9xuiqIB1Ni8G5oJUQlXHxCrbFnQdA0GscWzLFEB89RbonaDWmkJnODQaeE5xo0HVV6OBk5caDVGLYdb4I@LKzyMbyYk3onMS@QEkF5JEq/LZ/UP2/OHuCTt5uM8ePNv7jH398Bl7vvvkBFdXP31279HBHoN7/8nxPpMWpkfiYU3YoAS63rdaFh6qhzujZRhB3nOHMy53YnsKtz82B@yh27JwmGrbMwd3e/xDc6xxlYfah@boDPswbTqQa2CPcb4FnSYFzVhUbtq0@g7n8jPw24Q27QDbvAO3bXds8Cth23doW56/CIz1bchBkLf@utcEV5Lw4CiaOkRHvOEMrAsIboJ/HLsBMCaff0VHQdseD2C1NSYIF1wfTcGT/aPHxwzX7@8dPrl/cHJw@OSYPTg8gs@nXz948inQ8@D45Ojg3jN0Io@PD@8fPDjY2yULjkBKY7iC/tXEG69FQUPvRJXWGY5804nfwddirzdq8OzCpHWIHotOHJQ@ttm331jtaFmaeKi@4NpHGipgsc3do08/hzqfWa9xhNMfCqb5B/Izjw4w20yxbYoNCksVyltZFFeo9lRdofGIwYzheQZWmRbLx8icYD5wmsTTti0m7@EcFez75mvqqSz7oCGiDYCNoPwJKxVG55BEo4ltAlmF2Fp9F3dF5LHxSYTiA4Pe9aealCWimJgrg0BxvcKBg/1BejmwAL4HC0NEOx5xDywdWHAPLMMtUBU9wLkjLCt8TMaHExTPLMctXg2GD2hYmOUDi3smtWILAieeb5SlJgvOccIdBvp02gzv5aFT8EyvZdsUxCP/eBJLv88LhsXPAAOZyIcSaW4b@JRB2HRwqEFMe@OnZaIrcAPOEzI7Y4/FKorGTnBykOXY/Jyfbt90@BSo@dQd4j1WwD1kKmKarR2cj0MrQIYuMSCezbWIRxDuvtAKrQ8NByHv3YjRFHMk6Yw6fwrabQjcu4HALwIGAKkLLZ0W1VS03BTBuB3ByjHPBY7Eftt3Yf/Azu1Jy1oIIGZtxV7Zb94ogsiJhXaSP0@RsIMsemONQK2kocyOO4IyTmKVThRBKdjqucOxzfMwtpgCGnGiag58Y8UGsb2sVBdiQzpcj9FxnVCkTeDiFbE2gSk/JFbieD52Hoiv@fGSwPlQCfN5d4iO2cQTr@djZwkcRLqwsPsFFGEaK8fOz9mYMOH6pzSXHe8YnlBXqFTv3ztV371M4DF1XCzwkyH9SYd4A2NiXFA8aJyPJiyOUO8SJc0/XsibNDG0mIMnpCWWch8YtAN7NrTr7jbKgRufbnzTHtfIXLcny7dvKzyUipJJHBbq9WJz6ZZgNT/KBIWpMzEFJCQ7AVmQ9THfJkEwA3l9F9fFYC6UgSIOyhFst187vEeIED91zUkHJIs4Q1FkdwBfYVWaUTE/UhZXtoTzI/kidq8SryrJ@YQSFiJnzBfRCR@yriihaSlUX90Ad389OJDfHw6usBY7Xj18FLT7a6F9FG5qfDUsXi2FYH042HdrwPLK7RcCC2lPrAbMK8mb0AJOD5gzsRkJZtOuj/HljbyjsgdgsO7FHpQAaCi2iUND1P4exDEeQAmDmStExyf394@OmMzbJxAW5B42GdpCDCLsDfZ0PtvWdkjYaYHSFDSWA@XJt1mY0eZf6wrzUuKtEBVCB0kIegTCYn54cseecqknahZSIWj2PQlEn3KL2F36MsirCcBX0AYEZOeZFkqgtDSZEV752F54ErigW4LrxuE5/DTDmtfdeDLhaBYGFJ4TZHZxZcny/HvO9eOSHw9XsHCTG0xwGzRpqG@gnXAMEQ/Bo6Yt5uCabPGzFCfZcwU74tMOJ36lFjXsvz9DESNxJZzrwiGxLpRjgRrXjzd9NYcmJGI1YOJMT@HIZzSDgy/iyWY7nKHKvNKLLVZBoGTiWXV3w1wBwetX5eD09Ni8nqwECnm4rG0SNv9Pcc@21Tay5TP6ikImwQJZtkkgBGMSAyZxD5ccDEmzDHELWzY@bWy3ZcDuwKwz8zA/MPM@nzC/cv7hPM1XnNmXqlJJNpBembU6awVLqqpdu3btuu1b1RSWFyidlbALj2d6gbbQa8npIVkVzLZPVpX5/6mKV4lYTYrmMxujEgHy2urqq@dgJ1uhimd@FDavIcn5c3Q9gPN9BDKchCTeB86tHLoqPWKAJ0jHpvVqwCQKwlZnxpoSazstRiZ@gAvLhQAZjP2N1/8la3XEOIHbbOi8IpnQKctUG4whrBvKo2aK@g9PV4cT8rP1zf/x@niwYSY0HXxAq/yD/jAMIq88I4qK8Qn9V@PfguGwR9nYn@kaoaTJjelJZzvytmODV24VJpK@zWxJS3onsdmtq2QNVAmJFz288ROle4WkeC@TL5hN3avsl8USxeRrxWSR9tB2jLlnvtN7CgGag0kugcsH@fC9CDfgP@DgKpBAJvLmSxNtnGdxI4rArrlG97FIs1A5t@aTvd8KG34PQ3q49otQ2O5LKEhS2PLRnjNLsp4rxMoDcuGgl4ZSrp3xbCoK31Cgi5DiILg38buxYKGnhrKUfOKedj@bX8@tvbWodT135F7X3l64S42iLWDx9XvX4c3wrvlru3912xJdMfjr5bgx@f03IVZfi1dQ18pLjseaXytmKZjlG/i7Lt7miHMlgu8otuy5LYTHd8MJsSiic3hhXvC9aHRo3kAPiQSXiqVrxYXoYjcqXtfWLoq9Yq5wXetdFNDJb7RcHC3nl9P44SWsojDHsGa@NrrANdWUuga9W4FXhtLVbtI1RJBrCHw58Ied/n7p8ENMGocbABSBSVtvEqjzbZ9zaM2GvideL7hLSzGZK5BjLdwgWXPkFZRHn3aSJ6M4ptkBzKBXXNjNhmP6O3GsuZx3Mxj1KUUF40PWEvede2tOuTHlSKIAWWodFbKPLjkPx1GeNCqG@OuEragzed6u5dF30jFA1LAkTYf2uW2jTyEiKn25ahdW6AV@4wqRwOtt76mY2Nyky26B1UKPpHhoyuEPyWEid4GPqACBnwFpG7AK2rmH5PZhQfPxPY8P/IVkVCPykyEDeYt2ipiC5t/iG/k3UflNIAATfo73XJ4UccqdF2wk2XeQhAsYkyx@8Ec1A7pVcqfMYWMRNtdXjICTpTjRCKuVZILvc3dITqYV/JMtyOTpbaoZOr/D2YkkpKeWbyHSkrqUkrbwpxsVSxvFMqqYymyQYu5ZaqCkC45HBwEMq4nYCbpdQJppMReRAx/Jv1fWv6zrD2tY54VGntMzU@mZWLrH6YxUlMuDBT7KtGFmslPfonwPwo6yuVN1FQVtXjzo6YYHW5Iob@GpvKE36tc7UeYt3ZXMlTphM5aQMVK@zuh9TpmPldEMrtNrnC75e0X2vMYylvd9vH78tWQHBWQ8K21NElzq9Trdd7xo6RRkMxuoKQQXx/4mtuNBKX0w5XQCOziU89Ow3SpGUJbzasahMWNvbb63PbnJeJdOosFejFMDa8YYMahEdS4T4cbksAj1UPK8AYJgIqMJNXK3VOGJLDwxwGKueVUte0FODXBoWnKIF9Ev8h7/qMEeR07lS81OnGPMx9x49m6OE4gm3Xl7Npniswm6i/BH2agnVpGo7kkS4uxJ4tCQAus6A/bBbqEYfF7PE@ZEoWaKKbrrFEnpKENese9jXYiJD9Y/s0vWBx/22INuMBYlPGb45IVlxRzcR0E4CjG2E8WiCW8Ggy5qHWnDd0cu1DJQyMoqqlsiiMbK7lkVtOzh/C4@SYd0KOSJI4R8hwYiUUJ4026jMxl6wPbvcGpFiUtn5Fml3oQFGjBmXq2wm3kgbkLWmsJpv20iwT3HowcpHQ78RuBZsEcLYfdjcVNbPL6lPB39RjB6GCxpG5b1l5tO49edD6jPfZPPvcobJLuV6uCc9@p15GAFRFIJKznYxq7mX1uWoRtusG44gwBdsY8L/WfgzeA26PUCqwQrBmUMYdMaBsPboOlZ1nGglcAIF1kZNZPoh92/GTZYuAObLh@YEb2EQ5fVYcBh@IvrM6uLG6Qrcy1UWkXaZujq204TCag8Tlp91A6TwgLDBDA9sNB1MAKiLDkijhLpniUutHe5RkEUUAPjnBi6CU2GXn/UaUDPkCTL6gIoVoNElfWaCUygvkbXR@dgbxYC6B4TUUAhoFRJT@FgSaX5H8JByIYpHbuveiYLs1@fxgoM92DYgdk3IjD1ChUzcIcOPvlYqYrq0d7Jl9JxWcDzp@Ojz5Xd8q7YPiMdNyrKKbit@Hi0D7OL1qaz1vwIPtilKpS0KcEqHZ6J8s@fjsvVqjg6FpWDT/sVgAbgj0uHJ5Vy1RWVw539013SvgMEcXh0IvYrB5UTyHZy5FKtqpgVlRNHe@KgfLzzEV5L25X9yskZ1bhXOTnEylCrXxKfSscnlZ3T/dKx@HR6/OmoWhbYMGu3Ut3ZL1UOyrse1A91ivLn8uGJqH4s7e8nGnr05bB8LMhIwGjldhmwLG3DERZronbuVo7LOyfYoOhpB4gHCO67ovqpvFPBh/LPZWhO6fjMlUCr5b@cQiZIFLulg9IHaJyVfoYq0C87p8dljH@ElKiebldPKienJ2Xx4ehol2hdLR9/ruyUqwVh7R9ViWCn1bIr8M44qhpgALUgHZ63T6sVolvl8ATWjNNPaO/gQCd/AcIAliUouksERjMIbC0Q6ej4DKEiHagDXPHlYxm@HyNNiVolpAJaVOycmNmgQiDiidlMcVj@sF/5UD7cKWPyEYL5UqmWHeiwShUzVNAg4wxYByo9pVZjPwFe/AjMainOdak7RWVPlHY/VxBzmRs4oFqR3EJk2/koae5hNFxDiNLpo8zAvzYFK63pT7cBBpeclsjMltHoiEk7R7tlWJFlsCo7SjiFVWc9EUrJTIOVRifCayxkTTO4vGnXO71WH31MdTEWfFyHbRcvX3HwDopz64k7LqR8hQqkUvX651IdDrrVet1xv6dkDI3nSkgx@FO5HNlGjKePJ28U/GxsMN03Y4TaeikVnWSohwoIzMnUf8mmb/514IhsthnIYui8j4CV6ChktckVqlJgaiRnR7woI6qSJBP03pHsQAXTCrzXqKOcFC0jKVM/hD@9@@iFFwfjA8zOLO7KZvEQS2h0fg9UNVwJhUSgPzIiQadFVXphEPzaTufM6vDM77X7/WbacVQZyjuCc2A77TxT/DJoJ4pnkuUJWVI7y2D6oTp30xZG658lyYTsF29ILUvjn/qIfhyFDcd8QKkpVUXCaim0TL/k4miR5AoZ2gLdK6iTcc93UPq58gVPc7mV14XE94/6O48ttBfEILSw4NWo3AX9fLzgDDDAKBYHkKQjI2Rks0YZZW@iM99BxivMdNdpouUPrNVXAa3rQBLYyN74XbNOXI2HnbGJPczDH45LB9une3swdSK2r9dX36wVLB1262eXf8@wHooUS1HHBrCOwz6NkoxRsgMbHxopRiztiP2JgbNZzIiB1lWn0UeM86DtNuKWTDiRYXNDvDWmhyZ6doB0sAUF4Ji3FL/OHJmSAdKxpjrYmmt/TFt8H/ZKxAPSmKU7oV4b4x@ErYe/GuK6QZKBJItR7FzgXDhd0Lxn7ylTUTrcUOAezOLZio85jJumAYm6yH4WvWvpTfK20YshmzLieKVup5KAxHwSC6HsKno8sj9RnBEpAKboYfDlZ8lv8HgmA9xRuDs/HJVGVSDjni6JcupIGC0bXZOQL7aK0EUvX@qaNgVK@R2JFI09KU7WgUGM0UCo4N0gaOMbB1zQcUSSVZIF7PtFR3xjTsXgHQinIDlWvgPnzmqOhFJQ8UPku4pKIRiWDnLCVLvTdVgqy5mOY6HIGSPTD9GD4P@JNJkBfxNOnAA9opYRBPC7KElQmVZwfCWidO6UosHQbkTUND@dRWAezI650g2T2psx@9cACWTvTNSHMwp72ErPIAAyOQo2zPGrTdKufDg6vbcdWRz1JL3G9SAt5FqhloopuJm1C5e2Xa7SreCLIxyWNRkV7kNR8Z4Pbpc06uHIlDjKixehzeAcFf8ju0QCED3giUuv2Go1yVk5OcrUPCBDLRkLTlNHTIJt6cOjWrslYYTIjM39UvOlCAWgtxCf6XbSDSB9wea58YiLtBKLE4qCh/HA8ZiMi48MWXdJhpjdAOG8aJIwBC8JGd3hAtFl6BSqL4Im0i/IUAQriawOoziDON06HpCWltU7jT1JJpFDNfanPQ5EH7BUS@XwOMCHxNB0l/fEgT8BlLvf12xmsexSte@i7SJWxmIJWR4vRGn0@0PYOvrYbsDR7UwcT3yRQoegF94MZfxCWM86QymRUJt@qAa3TXx6p2WGY8ATamFnhN4KTY/4g5p0HaCFKIcnGWfWRBqYV/HolhI6dsbLeZHejFI2gSYUlpSIuCnWxP0952KCypChAVGwE@rDBdlsUj2od9DD764//BXXftwC9ZpBU0cmNUCSLJA7qdKjGI@NETd90A9JogFdgRIQTYk8C9K0oSqs0W8kO0m7JjuKjomxS6klf7wezaTKWgoqihhX1g7Mt5aBzkQqrcjQoDpYaH5llVCZdeB6ePQwRtFC42prYZ/39JSywZuI4gu1dcQnnjf10xk@SSF/8UWIowe@oI5bbkERYdyzol51ep4j/NCm4EsnGDZNmSjsZJr@AMVvdPTp94gXlehQhv1r@KMwmMAJoJHtjLMEo57@qX/Vq@/0u3670@/4cE7DMO5jnvHwcUKP2GHtYf8upLt@KKFpZGpOomeOL8Nh2PBd6yULRmiucBQM0qaZwmg4KV1xmAiSnKMRYHT7I/H3IBkjTZd5vRoVsuL@p2SPl3cKj5Z9lZ9VmDX6CEBOcFsJCwr2IR2RY5LhfFqYynD5VAYDx0uREb7ziMVeDOO3QCJSw8QwVshMmSWYjcCT2aMY15pjt0kxCIcYaCnYDfDKmTBNn10f79mFWeQdWgpsiPx6zijKWpQxxiHEh8nj5F558ydjDwj8APr5V7O4ZRYj0BTXUtGWQj6vyCijgAuZB3ZojqaZGGaxThtWoW4MaH2chBpPnjxGDbL8gU2RDLM3xZU4ItNw8MHr49J1mHLqEwcXlUWx6FDcDtyClEbp3OMMGzxnP0uDH5W4LDnDiWlHQk4bSD9GqgZQCa8UTZjXmihzTOXnR8zKyvf2WoKAxVkmZ8bVuWlb7VzIA6XD6yuqtfpDmIztBPWkqcdiOOoPFr@Teo/OHTMjs82idcNxnjUEZmYrwmK51CTSFif4OClYSXwSTBOnGFmaAQ/h8ZWeNZsniTgu1nG8FeuTZ@jwGM0iuym9qOj@bvLYx0XxFi161UKjhxThjkFKC/p7rQ4Nrz8@g0iYfLyq04xRxymjPuFHA1SCTJpK308h4j6Je4IeTaAc1tsE2pn98yhRk0ZyKuSpSooFuUR6YuB2dNqEeWnQQuMLDBPHO1w9SekN59idkCovn7nEIMOYwABxVxxkIjkUS3CjzkrwEd0O0ErX0VoojzMRPG2ZFg466L8mGEXll8IdafFQn2TyFwWGNNaQ4FRBuZ6CpPzN4bVWHxOUKVLAEJ9BCt2iqbnp6vtb9aNtgXwAgUtTsrT0zbnYGEcsAzbwx0yqj3EPHFUlS8ZGVHwg1GlqgLEAp5R2N@DjKu7@OkPmeLRukMMIDhD8OY0/y7IEhvNey2lqY5Fxc4JZHEluHm2OyGxxkYih@B3JL4cib3Xp4AoAAsYYyhfzAAHDmhL2qBSg0Dsm58UQlX0EBYt5HJbwkaKiRnaeM9KRqDLD61UjR25WjrcmjMxMILCxmJ0nQgT2LLOzRFBgoZuJi5Hjzez2RDlgQ6x4nykOXSF7JU5D3XNMQHgkbPWMUssLNyc5mBJfrzqxRM3flPo2Z6TmkqlAH41hLZNPpq7nYqmxaldW4kVjJYEejllrLBFI4ZgI61nhx/6Ra4oZ8lzbhBqHjNguQ9pn9/AodYfnNu@vodgkp2y1x1DwTM9wdfyq8xUrsaDsTwdgF4ukMsDY7T/cWmWZqjCRdwVQXDrl7JLmAyHtWG1c6rFZeNJVkfZ0gAJ1pu23xOeTvb1Y2NfLiTI0ug6Gq7lcDpn40gx@r2yrUZTU6WfjubOtm243O7j7afj5MktzfxDQlQAb6gQdQJfAoAi9/rDNN0MgDpAVc2ekIyue9W9aLfMKBtRQYudBt3FOGQ1B0ALU0UYvn09IAEQg5QL7CzYQ2/eL0KPvzueNpoSi1FBQGk2Cb22lPQPy4IcW2mdrTRUBw4lZWTPBuuUUt77hCoI3m1BnUfhi51tknmx/DLrdviu@4G3BGClg7iFZYG/PLJDjLKhhJO/em5Di0boiuO10Db9izGLyOoJTC5O6Z0LFhcfY@MdBuzwepO3aVxuWFWjyMjZzGeNTu8Ju244MFv8dYJkPAe3vyn3tD9INolMyMyz1cgRHT4DRq7w78@wTy@KQTEzS7PncSNTZ6HoUrAGa7tBeQMWyp@6lljySXRPXPh/nW0jDHMOQOGHMle8rga5mf960eDtqtb5vVqRrALhj/9CMyDeh/NiESDoAGoFy@AE9MYr2v2RgWO8lAorwBgcv65ied7BAHQtY1otG8be7dKlUEguD5WVRKm3DQyYjStslsYsftrfFLrxv4/vL4srqaoHn3F3nG3zcVh8fxDbAIAnncuNquAuvkFZEvzG01sYuXsgWF9zCQr24uVUIs7XSNrr1w9M//u0//vHv/5ktyZf/xpdteql91Zk8z8suNL4tvHwo4Htt92Jx4bK2MLhYbBeQy/5JUcP7lVHGj8xHveGlleJVwPhKdqTqnE3RZ2RRoW71u/aHv8LssiFSjTCbkl9DvjmK5thUIzC@B@hHeQlHeHXpQPIoD0ikAOgExfHQO40ADfBgvQFKAi5oB8rlWbeiBPcYDkZn0FqVlIzEQ3vW2wB9WqJICuiLCytWptMLgx5KwG9pz8vNsywffjujuuTf7NeDsL3dH4ul87RYyoklVyzZNv3k197CV2ch20HvXM4GxwHbdiElUi2gmaEIO7TRo/MD3bWTILdlLdCVPQhJhamgzOwF5@rTHznL8IVrYduaw0szBYtISMmERVLfFnoP0C3fIMeDHXO1oY1CXZ5iqDJDo6L7F7dAfsiGAFHN10yQjT5UiZo@8kjGp6z6IvvaotuECDCS9fjDHo17/ABr0UJP2jzHzlJ4zRGZz/NXXBsL7AxNaGMK1x8hQAoVPk7myJNwMbVosZW30UpqJnthm@2TzMe2DpNgpGzTudC/CoMJ2JrbJNxCT/q1SENuVq8Iu6PVK0ZVdtL2W1hGkeub7qgzkO4KVDsOqG@6tgceSdijBIjhcMz@jekRRoICFSkq0S18WdZENPvYdB4JPemaDh3seKw5MoiQ/ZqGsX2fGNtOlrxEFDswDxBS2pSv5Xe6oYy6MiRit/3hJd4O6LfoQrUR681InofXpCYw7rc00h5BJpPzaDxDU1KDod@@9l2ROuyfDP1JBZYt2PmMGp4DLcQQTIgEDj5Z9azmKYS5RbJLiCK6KWQ5hJcXdCfyejTuW1v7nGCXqqEgw67gIIixE1EyuI/1VYKOEVf/gU4wUZ6avLU2Uk6xNPOipZGEZJtuMzTMpoaOpWowx44eOLbFqOqRqXhBFrrBhfaaFL8wk3cxRoCs25ZegNIVYe0t1o@rUzvo@bHFadC1lKN/tiB4XcTxTFdRsjWSpW4@zUc33iFWsI/8Go8CwWuTCmdkzaXTc@ehvM4tZa4jFORb2@JnfdHRF9DRBWbkGSJOex2eLBMrVHQHhicqZPkPEFpdvw34Te78CbLieSr9bj7r1L6e9y6W0ue9@/PfHcJETslqlc2IlFRmqxlLjhVYGbNu7FVZpYUq1OB5L57hvCfYh8UgASCSTde@Zi/us4DQeQrvlD9PMUFiXYaYZJ@uL4vgs1NopuJYZFPWnLPkqM5Pv8s7AtZW@sU@5A8O/wIW6lBJYno45wxbAIr8dH@7YZeTMLu@knu9kn8NJ6F2MM4MgxtcbzPhzWUwhq1EiMdZWHrOf49xQ4wQD@PQL8DHMbSTrzVh35NQOinJKVQOc6rH0mwFZTzmCcgPVKZwqeji4ug8Piof8cDvCmA5lZdiQbHpoMF9aVw/w/411uOHOK8lvUOYI9HKgG1ESISaQcjq8pXHONRRw2WR/Jw8sYOxWwkIdG82ZawWvX4vIzdrjrdYwE00es1013PrueQYnRqisRG6IDdTi/Miv/Xuzd//6@i31Ci1tZL9MoTfUeq31Np6ih/hAd5eqbfb1FZqE7OtPaQmWTgDw@Obv/8PlN/6CeBgymQT/mytKlhrk9RWpkhF7lNba/CQX1mBev/3b3@DNizwiQ3vYl2ou4IQKyiK7Pg94l1IFxVsJR9LF6NphRyzEAZbGMLZHF7QMGq8sp4jMV1KWlXcBjLylbJHkUs8GWaNyFSIJRnKngJ2RlygiBVkGKQyoWgJw3ZDmW0g80Zoil9eeGshnAB@keYcukptuvEiRJOhBT4WQQemuUY4z/PDVu6drc07NmxlU1JQW0g82sm5dv1V4f8A)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/1bzif)

This answer was tested with IE 4.01 from Utilu IE Collection 1.7.2.1 installed on Windows XP SP3.

IE4 ignores `+` in selectors, so `*+a` is a valid selector in IE4, but not in IE6/7.
`*+body` was changed to `head+body` to break it in IE4.
With `*+a,b` selector, IE6 ignores the entire rule, IE7 ignores only the `*+a` part.
`+-color` is equivalent to `color` in IE4, like in IE6.

[Pada-pada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3eVHgU8ebE):

```css
      *{+color:fff}   a{-color:000}   *+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}   *+i{color:000}
IE4   *{color:fff}    a{color:000}    a,b{color:fff}                i{color:000}
IE6   *{color:fff}    a{color:000}    -                             -
IE7   *{color:fff}    -               b{color:000}                  -
```

All other rules do not apply in IE4/6/7.

IE4 doesn't support `position:absolute`. To avoid scrolling I commented out most of the polyglot before html code, starting
at the second line. This makes positioning of `<a>` and `<b>` needless, so I removed that.

Space in `* +a` is for Retina.

Answer (score 3):

## 312. HTML+JavaScript (IE 5.5), 14428 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
*{+color:fff}:,a,i{color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
+i,: u{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[os]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on;z cop>s'0}e}eq67+?4[0]tfc;text
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKk9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vq9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrdGGrs3Y3dN28saaUlCX7uj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d0LcE8z5lgX7MBp2W2AxMbumeXYb6wRuGUYu2/13w7ejlnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeypCR@dSeuMmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2DOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1zijMokuBscfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@2j3yafX/Osp9qkJSA371vRa9LrOntvWqH09hME@P3nw4Lptmn2mug57cBMlPcN2J2P3YHwdfpbtdi3HZIZW1Izrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD2wR5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILL@xxT4MAJy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@x1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mZNbtwR5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQma7bzUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@4ue5QiUbKeL6Xg@t0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwhOhi1x7bR4QLt0WvTIiytNoLan5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4pyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@cFT5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@4/uR9l1YCM2qgpBSStsEvGWMR3ZOdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttjHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2Z5wBS7dtnKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SriQoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3HCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9KzXE6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKYLBPTQvbDmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDmwiR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOUe6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSfRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurEz1nPHSwmjYuXgyDpPRurgP6FOYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrngPWdp3oOIByMYLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyTVCadJ1QnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjrM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUgWoY91XNnsDjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@sYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyW5OBr0wI/jgXJ3nv6dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qju6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrN4QNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gVdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzjIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92I3rwcX4tdvkl@lnA4KW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSY3kw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@TUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4hbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4GdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Rqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfwuSOJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMe6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9HriFH702a9vR6M6OFltorTzo3R6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPABBczxzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vY/cK7JBpBmdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abK3ID1GTJ3uUWhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAT@QEhRQBotkUtSfaEFKHncjdYZbThzqHmAxroEo7DJQ0aECiBEyNugcdsseN4SWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsK2Hl3u9H0UBSg2eNlBARiTZ2j8dYNmIKpBc9X3FsQFsCTq1U2eW4N4ISR99XEngCskoOcrJPWJHPT@yzSft6RjtoiZ5kLHWgK9mtsVyWoPLnpaGyjqrRBaqC8h9FqiLzYngCfYN5yRYzVBbeRpaHWm9FoBLK4RhiIHh1KYl4UGE3Z@i9WasvVAJugsLOpVET0D8TLfVAECWETuAX2hsllQPB4sDhsKe7Jw8roixyx2TTdkoLFn23ZfbJehO9y37YRwf3jnaPvt5YAqNvN0vXLZJ2ppDDqnYyVbvOJJnRjNJmGMYc8P3GetgYcNGPLAlnprrTkKo0a0HlMvXJeXj02XWSgCaE5KAYwIz3NZWG@wGlS2qaXu9aJcy68ThEGQTx/TL1gPkwAwOiju6mj8/TyZs3mHnXkRoKe8SsPzE5AN8yeeD44TR0vKaA@U7NDq8RKSxoobaD/Z9zU9inj8@nqDVfR4ZU6RDLfHr4YP@oQmB7pndm9fsqeUl6Y9ClzFFbA57vT9qWtMwPiD8wtVhcmyOO@jThupTArdYCged5y1bABwDYxNFcpvYHftK8HuC@dz1tZKu2Ag6gb4JwXa8M60Otj0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhXlkFVktrrMB1sdpqZbNWPlMMV1uteZztMNABKcW26@uNI3A681S00eZapFCrBfrHj24g7pESCU0B1cfM6zON4vL6ErZeVJtFveQetNDcvqU9J4knM1lJJqN@x6fW8qjNGfK/P7XHsZTC37oCfiH23d0D477vWXTUUQcGNRqwCY4106iDAw0tD3jEcftu12VbEIZrh36EoDatTOZu13Vu5JCJlpjUCI5cgPzF/hpzCHWN/YYajhQq3Fzlox6m412AlNZzaSQSUYhAJcm/9so8N4Fc83QfH3xjHyoRPZtKBeYUXUCCUBgiF5paIVuyYCpEpAl8liYwGMW4Udp9BzU0jICJFoIuCLg7d15qSRJTSy71vxSlr7o3KP7KnV1jLbDhrAWGEMkOnjx9dPBk//HuF6djI5td@M6kijkgHMTXBF1I63G6YWnd4kUTk4XgIlA2Rli8QApMoIHid4dPvBEIbg29aByBFVzDx39iX3V7TtRTrifmAl3VV06Ls9BjLHzcqwgIDe12HxsjIz5shvU58k9vPB56pWQSSnlv0tSg0Zp81XL7ZjdJ4aBi6PeTOjZdDg6xX8NbFgKQ8WYWD8H7tEB1mFHHodkfuNB4oaE4FA0sxsFTZ1Xf7vagLYzjddZI0QIOptQk29BCgLZyMkgbCWD6AtqKt59PMmftr@hGgfO1njIySdn3tlD8we9Gx4KmUwxqKyCFcu2Tnd45vcNmIKUR0nUgEaZtiSEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9HqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDraljD4yILe9wkkNV17cXrq1EFBP71DuOFAWG1Wr@l1pcxuBtkS/pUycO9C8pB3fQvgXTICa9KbrZBnbfOmOGubVLraLDkeDEWdow7Z411QpN64IK/bVrjsYYBk2DG5teA3iZ7fJZd0CPUxqIQPpFQSChTUtMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQBs3pvB08GHn0NyBBvdyPe2G/Worx71Guwk9YZAROpjbqGU9rB/cAy1Y8D5KKUhc1FIswsrit3npsc7KSGQGHT0w0NbLYBAnfFBR7QTDLYCE1Aoap6D5AC@wt7S3ryXERv9wGkQIeGEnQ@gQTg0aNAFOQOBeUJ2eUJ4TGSzmKQzx71wEFrTYgW1aY95H787GeFgnt0Opw28pw3uB6BR4kJynUb9mlaL97LywJQKaASabGANXOxKAO2KRIFFSTD5iCG2BT3sqIZilVJx4ATgq@zuHkixlsX7i9QBNqKApfZZdDxK7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVJn43PIBNmX7iE4B6IoMRbOolET2gpJ24A/L0nPpb0PGer@5Kw9m4BykGDpPNiju0nOttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sMrqxsREtRavRBJh2wLSNph00xcG0QyaVTOhPQxOFSJAJXWsUAu3q0auaD3mq1JEHpqg5vLGHMbNWKqXrCbOmi7eBbwWyAigPvlV8AZyoUqmgUVHk6gUO1YD@Hkr7HvLOcWtkDwUJvgoKAf8WNEgTEaB5j9r8yCpj23Q9RQaVETQaLVQxY6PoaS11Wj@9PG3HT6@iCQytlM0KtA9BeI1jA607cidDUNxqmZIKsk2ppUv1crMSTUW3YrGC2oeITEX5pKDETU7rWNQCnoqdnkaBpII6tVZvRPCmCUNRAkIBHh0bWhn9fiyqXRYg/qZSV@JRCKtEEyCWK9Eo0KWFRPAo0dgjwJnogT0FUkLBhCouPKZAApLGpLC4fsMa9majsIeg1w20bOxBnw/GQ2EgKR6Wkm94@LBCt9DS9/Ve7g@UW@y8Q31pOOPSXeKYniYXJob49e652hm4YzP5uQaNJi1UXUY3oklVhZqQXDgkSvZj28MibDqWO/HCPY1LO0AxdrA96U1AWPqzZhLAVfZQslo9l0U37wJ0FgzzYFWCI1YqH/fyAbRbGtwoRFErwcES0C5oOokNchGnmvBeGZ2Q4KLH75vP5oavtSC2MoVhKYzI7jruyFKBJBBCoskfNFVIqjIxo@SAer5ujEsIV6rSsOFtWyARH/Rdk2jLxXVoPGg4CIWH9jkEObLaUh/kRwfEo8bzYmS1k1sSDc66ox7UEJAalMRGkFsD4ZB0vWFbG08hqBTDCjfsyFt3oHResLZhGLlWtlPy3ZArgNg9yCRslTrQxPWdVB0cFZHJ@7xbyG@jPzm8v8/7TqiyxeoV@9EaA7c9Ab1StJuOLKebYPvAT7bjDmwggx/@zVn/yHXHvJUPH6t6Znij2R5M@ib1@VzvllkbruU23T51Ba0LOvc/GXlm3@SdUL7r7uePQdd/dnJc0UohT0nzfLA2buyHXB4tp@dBeMyRhln94SGPM6a8mZWx3vIno6GYEQ45dJiIqWiQR759Hu39IoVjKMK@gPYDnIYGurLoRaDPwFJ4LJJHnJqGM3qE5aWeukL7lW2wwJ9O/rjiOMf2UjfI/nzc6SxYp8n6TEXR1J9bZ8iaT1FbaCOGUcpyTzhfbcFPGFCO/ATT1q77E8IrmGLQs/r@COIRKCY4SgZ1ex/VJ2iboCbO545ZoEgPcTCEJDQOsbEW6JrejW4LKFNDlfuWIhtUTqAOS6LmIm0mmejiLlNJcVwxNOlx6elC0556T7arfMAam04j3mpL8s73zQaA2K6W/dlEq7xhTNFo4I2gEm4QgpJJw/Y3khpMwvCoT12iIGXJS0KrYWqk1NNpfr@e9IgIHSafnk4/SRlfQOMD53xt3kl2rTJGt5Ja9M37oVs9EBssPl0kGeTDxOm4/bbKB70g/xlvLmFGiKkGwawzEvhgY4/8CWc2TmIREwNBXIbmqt2Aey3rqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyyt2eJ87esBjXYueYN@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@ZZlPBBaUIHeqaKAlhSkji5jCLpGYREoDqcjevkULmW0ajNhAxhnDnL5XfpsW5OMjF5B9JGZAh3UOEhpiegqKjlNJ9htvi@O/6MIbBsnzazqvei6Hw3Gd03bOXBpFCkyNlKZnUc8MQg/O@jdDdmyvR48FrwEO3K@xCjtv0OzQY4kHGkwRw/RkQd30QsOG7DSTR/SiHvslMS9OTVmItml1Jk6XxjTRzNTXt/hUiwXy3Gk27VVegQg428x/L/EGshJLnqFlNN0vPdjBA9UiyE/eJpon/fqsJrZAd6ikxhBKvP/LN9tA/5u504P6CvszA0MDNAXMKbWzMrNEUPygx/KM5d3uk75tEmHIdBvIljmCJJn9wLAcNA3tqyroGwMcqBA5DryJD9BF17AZx5yPM/rv5ZEsG6pzQG63Vvm9NsuLR0WDStBcbBMRuM5lWxSIhCzPBGvKB3ZCDXcUuLcj5U/FYsTMPN97k/GEP0EdvjUT7SHe68qm8JnKmk3dggap2bStNVk@Ms8mbVcdnnUDtTi3xO889TSyrIJWIgaZG2hcnnyewJHdheref6/yNq9fkxf0uo0rPGfiDdUmte3b/IsKwmBNDKM@f67yYouVSoFhNdXsPj0@kBMFdGAUMcciiTNY1RDR7Gtk7pvNGapCvY/nsmC@AkicSiseT6VXDFgPh6vDY/uUwheLy0NPtRanx7KehySfJavyvjlKsJg3e0uuQnVlD8y@arRDxpXCfNl0hxteg5FSCmOd4zjR@dKcm1MfK6TWpG@O5qY1LD7Hwx@cWNXPLaoNUZZbbt/2sED3V0lNf87dPC6cp0yP0LwKexkl29AQxXpcDUzLpYDbGuNc1BVs9QEyjc8BxZm2IT7R3FXEarkXeK/UIHrQGObP5ZXam6VYfYB8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@HVC9uz6LGcsGdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8jbM9u@967Jie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8f5QIRcIKV2/RUj5GpDr6OK9UrSfJUdnt2UQrf8a4cTZkHFNLbtMUolBndWpg7YBjgguT9mDVIFCakneh7giYhzLuTBn/vsXqD1WkdavPYYz0qhBwcMAxQIYxiOuZf8isWXWx9b@MKF0A2z@tkSEMvesb0F9Rc8bWcqMlP6RIfRU6sNFVKc/sSbW0rbGYfOVhcuI17QzPhyplEjGphgCwFEHXPMS@HojGocfhDVW1fi1VpiY0Gq3btdmFoXaEBTwIbaen4LhKRpuhug6k@FCri400Jyj9STrDf0i7bYXsEOXj5VDhVuUpQUV3bPoXtto4o08nHlWyaRSKaHDhIZyFj7WNabSQdhXNn8uREw285jnfnH4bhQyLo@DyBKe27hSBBmr2vbkuVhMOrZjjWf4/EBp2nTd/sfkFAjVto3aGCiXNId3XY7dUHfE6hQ2773wsM@j2VnVb8FrG9G8BPpgu3ldpofHmj4oN1UcTR3gSNfi5/oenNDI1W2x4HJu7Bbis3r7q3VJ0SGiawUtv7bUcQ3VbVp9k7@mucw6eEUtvRbeotAQo8A4aszHiudj/JFrQmk4A2LZbWio9KyBRZ9rFH2z/Wri@a@VnqYu3qucp5bVSk73rdYqD0Mb5IKDz4XB6ZCyNHYdaGKNcQIhNlX6OEVV2K6SwP5w4lIiHwzMrsX3qFgnKed9FjhNh7fs5sblvRclPjWnBcHmPcyrWQIK1Zk18/z3UoCPZy3I18ng9h63a4W/hd2gH1DaV82NvVnFOj235/SsHp@QHnytKhzAj2O@p8g61AHrbg/nyA2HC3Pnw/Tsu/3@h9ATRSMXlK7bWYrTPq6qxSVhHwV3ZjbBQbxu7b8zx1x2oGFlqelZE6iXPHfsDi2VvlZ57WNfD3@ukqH@6Pcv2om0tqkPFPHfvyj8W9uWXdMdD4f0agz7E48eFFSlxdC36U0dPueFZlu6o672xh00NWGpiQkxNOi@XMQ07XGrh4vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9Xh/@@UFtV6SMzdT7aK31bSDvaKYhv1TC7sf4OliV6aIDiVdrgWGNvrKsk47We6tD86zl8Q5RNLES9gmHSiNfFV6i5fSl1xN7PAcamiQV9PDykQk0rMJdTMtYqVnR4ou5GBbTNVZyKSnpqJCrVgoUHn1l/9LCBLpQEUun@WMVQuFUEkahCS8fQ24xqYg6CO1Q1y3YL/DXwmyopZWc05t0vZsCk/fYt0FFw8fqbguaJB3qtYY6y3TEaxWZjX4SV0/CuwE618RaO6ySXTuuQv70vmq6Nrwa8IKsm6zsQ@vbQ48/mdpZORonJklBW/z6kCGnzWx5Y1pkTNvq8FEQNN2mIg5cGqcFHURt4Zg@dqKjMOeKFxdcjtsFoa722dyz73eV2rJ0/tHy7A/qTPWLJ1bXxEncj@wxzgJdwhXEssvmLd0K@2sT07O/NoGUrWI23AqCj0SOwnsG4NcSeI/Nrt16uJARAZKCwGIKKX8tsD9a3cyLi57t4RyqwLCmYwpZjjMxcl0D2g1LfF7vug92wZgXIL6@cqnvZd3r7nCGy9BmZFrXs26PqZdVvFc1HVfNLluLxMVkMJx44rUcB5qlFe6FHpyRvXdhA3D1NYhW1jP74@U91aEuV9DCRKU4N67Sxr9h990u@0YhxUBpAyUMlfMljHMPquenODVo5CzhRIr7A0c@saNDHfGEvYa8tdJMtR17vL43ZzzGaUL@GxPDaw5c@pB8hE/t7sdCUE@WU@TR7br@fM3zLfU7cN6xOxm1LDQGG5mEmwUiVmvPn9aMS0Vc3IjlItxKWzt6A9Wh60zG6mjirK0VcmtrhRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/fqaEuYGmgd@mhVrQ@Jt4/dnctHLOwDUmsx1QxFbL0UXfflviPt936YjmIN8SZhc3h2qRuL7vLmvvPJ2NrPEHN5hA@E8G960WjhzeGvcT97HruFAbDUFQDo4svpnAwlyP5QEx2CNcLg/0ad8azTGBXVEJcW3DHFpNyN/@3PQhdREHfN8cmyuqIuobpPZfYLqVV@x@0xq9ok6/kHlVk3YRoYfWlNoWqxmGl0F13GpxlRj74xbKyMKIjTd0XYc/Sdqm4KU/Xi9VoCqgx4ePlWs4w3@hX2Bp@2wxqYfnfKKI1ea7XaxK68hqun3@XDMtybH5tABzZFte8hFunkB2uQxTQfvy1sqQ/FoZMm8agSZ7bno0Tr@8qTEHqU8/YhZQzxy1XBwJE4Y1E3RCOx7cIqaDRQN87kATCD8FiWW2JmLvxdvQ6g@aA3qsbDCEcvPIauJyoyZtEzI2pzczk/cMiT0SQpO6gp0FfHGFhTrHYk@hNaLcXm0ttKMWqWoP6UGSeuVwOc3XUR3bar0xsdfMJXrN@6YX3CHNySdkXNFXHSpG1IucNGkJ/dKStDh7DRSavqWOeyNo8yfH67q3/f1bloyHTAYWDjIvjsKsVF1dr0eJdZePpwfCdWSpYu9AkCXBPoJcP1R3V2qeCB7@h/e@moRKuJHL@HuagOi6fQQfkJ@MHPH6EA586nrjjj09BLxx3cEqcYLJykIQePGSgaatVYmA3HMmfd770A1NvRq0qTmm0v61qtoncT22VMs5V2mHuenNFLl8NVlyFzdDHVttVWywgCMN6iN/YVngTbyXDKCGZSPO99STnLDTXEbMAF1G3AtfMoC@5Y7VoUfv5NB7evDo8EQbevrS@mm3h@sxbuhxCzs2GIVUqEvqlTkKjXfyGWlt2xsn7x3r6t6jAw09rKA3H9FQ4YUjcwuvlf2eYutRM2mubAWhqzVeriA@PHn8KD5f@8lie72RO7CUsPPe8XEC17Z89Xipczj0AygdHXe6MvjBvq4rS9j3mUOjg6uk55KYVkE6saA1Csz4kG/4cqty1XKHVvtkNrQ@h8oTJbj3gdHnVibyiXlud7EUsuJKQlFBZUUtl1FCk7OhsW2Ngveq/DyzhygtW/RK8tfK6SioOaSTo/Ry7WHdiP91LYalxEyEjwukp25y69hWoWR0e2hKmt7fFzFd11fR@djsQL6y7MrMWvSwbHy4755/wFCyJRovamCljoGrVPvWqeR5dQCiO4kP7J4XlmBsrpwGsw5AYJ1bWuAvLGdmOiqNZa1TL0oQGie1rfXyDesDBqSCGT7nuCH00jG@YFY9i7XIqNwS8ckoFGRv797BbQGOBC3X@/r0yTP21PRwd5P1HsMYWx@A8VwzeqVivxVurbdyOLU9AlDGWnjd4fLyXGLH5qjtOrPp7YNwtLgVq3barDiAhV/kyerbU3tZXdXi/VpPl08zui1uvo7DnS3oweFdbwSg99/5Z7qeStGeRvjWU/zzlpzxCziLocmc4UZ5YaeTg0A0tFBv0cBCWdoafWRNcToK7w1e1qhfWr/l1tR9eWV1dbLOrbDGLbMmvhtuaMnSWkpfAzC7xo1lNe7M1yYdTZzwbrleQux3wJcU8kVenuZvaRyLOfG4oizumh9e0sYXc@GeanwdFvh9@5ZtiOVW4BCsQBOLvHDrJdD9LFwaKREIXHsXcyoVPVtkO7h3fQkku0IxglWJ73DjR1Zjm5di8VSppF/hAjK5JDOxuC3YsJJvugiAcbs4SBRTz3S2OQaXTX/pFaNtw9lbRuoi1E96NgVfWjK8FrYs1qQBTpuXTw@e7h@f7J48O66l6leyIlZectwcB2Lz1@R@km7LkHhBN2BDvgUrrd3sQ3S0pTmqmZ6fLgYpu5a0ykLS5omSdzDM5qXjJJO0BDGpXgF@qsxjI1eoU9CKw/ZTTBkkVpCW@Mq9PpFU3uSgZYoTMq3EUssiHpqeB8kS7tcPVSBXlk6jK49Y7JoJhb/rum0Ro2ex2y8/xge7B4@eHe0zH8E511zY7XGvUszyTVVRVKsW5FPHptkMFRYVQaKQV5VK9EEUCBPVoqxECz9pQ1NgdPDmUweXjIrQWyy2SfCBgtEgU5L/5ZvJq6iGE/MU8Bv1kYoyQXn0wE5wMdef/aTNN/z2t3DwTw4ZDUgu0VJ5SSzUXLFMEylKJXO4@vwQ2mCbVmQGO3vPz2SRaL934MoL2n3p2s48Cm2WwQ@DERsn@RERg/ibBGMPD26CBM3TcxuXY3IcOrgn0SIr46Aw7cOlsV08HAV4npm06TygPnHGfN8PsUtABPhICyRKgm0SsnyLejnkMbq9AazctLq2wzwH1GZrXGKvgM@wF6XE1wSrajV6I4gPmp@Ko/bGg37I441NjLzk6Tj5/te@m@yWGZinqXvw9SviqwPmX@XmF0nM65sbHc3jDyOBm5MJrHnkAc2R3qFzYBy@9npOLNyPyReVzB5A1pwTpdE7j4E/VZCwczix2ueQUcBikEtizTWPzxrVY7g7WimZRDbCESmN5plaUz7p49ouablsLqMnAUn13AdI2xp3cUEbB6goJWB86dweVl42gb22t5mMWphVyZV5biY3nRdp@WWA6Cb4lS56iFyNQRgIMg8BblURDOqTuK5gUJRHUT2KoqjtQkVD7lgh4bcjCCGzGBCL08jCfXKneCDQeDTzd/tr4iE7oS3vNwUgVYdqhkyKLIllwk/cMbDMwgJpvkwYJz3xSg230fL4gVe0yR7yoHazNM1Xt/l764vypWG556DSqev1Yzhv5ecI4hhBlORlLFt7wU7Hp049yXmTAZv@SLBsmJkdMP@TZHcFz/J0797cYi12fYM0JBa7e@y4qG4@gMSwmJE00kk9p8yTlMksTZJIkYgGkoMbP7yF6EA0gZhoWfYrd@jt7u0ffPXw6fGNbcTIZ/S6N5Dk1e34qaolavXAEA0nazFL7j1IHj@@98DPiDnSuZAEBvVFpERfl5J5KxJBzmclX0/aMgyvp241xs/50sXr@KaNdahRoBt46KmPiJdmBqoPaH7/9ciNwjJqZbPrUJrDS4ZA7/HFWTdQjSmXV7X6dvXUiURvcsKSgvAiom1hIQDTqbe1mURmv5k4TFhwMN0JHqnjhctienlZlDfTuJsNLg8du2fzfXyERcghlF4/GhCRkpb0va4sfYdc7Z7vNmXwg/P4vjfh3T5CCOdS6ygeAnXin8GHUmS@V57YJq4Hbbm@3ZT8XVb4dnH@rlbBTnF8h5SYIokd13nEMXEq37Q01WgaQExBaUewEmzdznM@PEWCAo362tMJtCmfukO@Ay8N99y3fNORC@L3/oSPG1vsq5MB@OvQ68iirjeQ3CoEBkpGA1S5/gRSQmw8N43j1n4QXw23nxMJ1wbtbGyqaD1r2ra7INtjSgIk2ie6XmfB5nSYaNqMzonKlGfzXFhbFD/FJXdhsn/UDoXTOQJmzdRsp21NY9GLqFKqQ/xoH714fh5V5GW8RDsliq0D29e3TAzQz@vrJYk5FqXT349wmbQoFm9KCbC7Dpjv9eMf/1Esaj1PolOcKqiLH49Hj8AIakSsMzCHLDZx@H5IGqPP2GnMSdAGMmqVb6nmsHicmkjwIgeNUcgOmXj9HTOdGYslK8AEaOs5bXy9sYespmtaHcwUicI28ViePdC4cG8RRYJmLQQpEdgKshA0HAAjXkg0zuAQBt0l3PJlRLtKLXGmU0qoh8JFmlCqWfUOC52utKg5ysViSWToolQsMuC@m@JQSwLYG3LO1@WBumLvAqAZNGg1KTIX5DclXoTijXBEHopNDwCdSGgbRH8vBAaw5psUtnojvGP7DpQV3L6l9OzkQaOgJGUWbJ7QHdlt7EHjO/kGjTZx9gIU0@SC12iZt9E@xWC4K1aD786AmzY9oAIjXxOpkTAZrp81OudNXV/L9SKgyAXwmcEKQKwwafjgcPs3fyxzidtyYf/zn@NppnJscyeXbvTP49FsqgwPvZxlWfbJ5qmqbtaMbKpyd7NumuNTmZnJzNb9c6vXaR50k6eyzNIsk0xuGbnXZ0M9t/Wipr2e1uVaoZI4qz89Y0@ffvGu8U6Rp@cz@TTG8hG2d/hW1iEBkVKeFRneSy86ZnDptaaVLkcB7ukpnlIq5@Vkshatw5@cXsLFPdWqWlXbqb97p9TykKbp7DSCh/@xw7vkTO0k6moyDOXYtu0kOx167Tbcbo/V@fG1EX7F4zGVCQu1xu3YYNohu@mu1e1O9s0Zt7cjE3w9GIuwj7/x/PlzNDyni705EuE5dObHUWqY2QgzUsaf/XTjKnH5tLH9Z98aJK0NfB3i67tXj9F8rGc/2dj45N69TCYBVOLmp994@vXd3d3M/UT2aS27k1FTG9t/@icbG4axbSQ36p6n16O1s7MvZCOVkbU/@3G08fTp1zwPswWvNNPBiM8C3DrqVGfsDVxnHYZ/Mr9ph8wmmpudN8yIvIkAW0dm9GtEGC@FFdKSwtcG06s7@f/6/cPXkXGkaiSfj@A9jryO5AoRbgQDfKX9r/NINbKN3nJXkVmyUqmAMf9f/x2Er34V4KDLbBse1awPKzeLVNUKBXkbqebAoBsGxPt/ffObt3T73GU1uORM3pB36nBt0bUt4ZZVaiqZvOZdL9zR7zDmjHtjy8WXzV8OvJhZdqDVfVSLx@N1TYVLa1CgpK4bp9RhE2Yt6m@JBNZlxm1YyG7OJ8IG3J5HiKeAqYivuFlYEKtxi@fX/T1fcpWf/0NfR1Ikt3HXul@tgig0qsZWNU7XxmmpxMmfZPmC7Lp3sUcreipH2Uv2SBC7KqcKhpxIJO428GxoNkWaqtPInICM04hFFigbYfMvFraKMD8Ym/v5WH/7eP35//bnP/jz79PvB3T/R9zdy2nbneQWR/68yi9WrcrVkXx5Sh93WapUKBWSDXZ1GtuqVetHTE99@jaaTUePMY3kiZ0qfg9nJLiqVXz4aOBXNcJtqtw0txMu1eCDfMyDLPfHhGTyiRqBKlhMglJr53WOG8fv5lW7C9kkG/miXK8aWeMQsk6XKeOKrLfpMTciUrQD1wb86A/XDnYeCxt8bpAldyGvS66NAJXbrwUspUitlqxbdVBkWdUHcnejtFEo5UoGZMpqwOVVoCPnYWmi5bWCZoD4eFfbYEec1@ss7l@n8VuvZ5rWEEYyuHirqjuNSJF/gKsqscglXPV3W7V3wLoi6poop/FttV6NC4zgpTXu1uPq1VVNexEvl8V/uxoYy3RxEySkfqWq2y8AVu0mVA6UnlrjxTaAjW/XtivuHt1aA0ms1l9Ua9uLYUXwu3fjKGPvAoDqZp1FM240595lSjy@qaobtZVpAMD1GCgB25CBV9tX1ava9tXV9jb8t@l5Jd5ge7V940@v@bXCz9ydis1pLVk9TZ4KtqnDt5asoo2WPAVDFd7gD6ohKQKKyVSKbLGtyJDp@TSYmFXSt4x0Mjv9JLcPqlGtrmILpqLW9Fy2rnJJ9VJjJZVvCa4XcoqGoqjhdhq4ik9jL6XIy/df/i94n77/8vex3odiWZQiyS1sHhR5KwEejx32@PFjvB87DvzhfswvB23Q4jHaOfzhcB@@n8Ca22BxAKHAZKOQkxtxfWawyLacy6NY@KUbVzQa/UcvjWI@ylvQuNrtpQeWv7Ts@ke/tOqSIm@LWM5bHuNpkiJU7iEvoPxU0XiJj@Zr/D16g7/XY/ydtPB39Bp/7OQN/o7G@GOPm/h76uHv5DX@dpv4Oxng795r/D0e4@9ZF39SpALa9uZOqp9qpfQz/QwMNkuNWKqX6ultbAqkLJaapWYsNXD1Npgs@KXAZKc6LNVlKSfl6Do4gmHMUmM0deDVhV8HoIzgZ@OA95meajGIpQ9A@bE@9H4Lkkw5lWrQhpRfWqAXa7qW0nJ2HTdDr8l1o1hgGpJYa9RenkbruMumUcyw5szaOH3JIh7o1OVI8vQ0yXsHmJEp477pV1eNxv6T@41GEmXR6WP3cP4/PByEP9f@B4fu40N34ML/8PDwMbOq8btx9S5clWp8W7x2ItXyzmlJxYLry4pIcnvntJpW0ZyLQ/E30C7@kdccIryrG6dSlIGqclEmhah8cV6@KJMh@ARDoxx4EN64ASzLQpECm7KvUV3AdX5BlvhA48Xz08DEDcnnF6fYMIAWX/AHjTP8@d/gb/@/6//4GYvV6qDgxC6vtmN0KfhTlMuryyvxrCqxmPiIbcMPLeAbg1xeVdFIni7BVIspdeXqitvBM6Zsc4BVjGO7SoHnHqH0R4I4KV7@iP23fWPc4jrF/bjN@VD96ek0lVLKTX//XxymMt/SiKlSptNcNps1vf6nP6ZdnncU8pTNlMv6FuMfRsYolzP@V75QLhf8j81YrHjzqqZ29BxoOJmMopTL8LHjg03BZwC2AGD9jyxAtTyzReW@HLk8OKT9j0FMZCMKpogLhliKtknHEzeickm@cycmTvLc2VXu3DGKqbdvA5vhEKz0BatGo22PGg20T799KzdkGjovZuE7VXj7FmRZVHFHsSd4UAtEFFN19olRpTiL7ggIkQdnpieNORY90zPH41HsjT1MyDh1x5MVOkchlXJHp9Gffe9b3zqNViqyKpNtRkcAGAvLbm/nMtVqLgPmXAEoJW9e8iNFuvGirlxtJmVODSZvRiPCSS/kFS4bo@gOVRzbqUIB9/Bil1cRynaWySoxkK4KaFpXEfxxa71Y5PYsk4sV4kXxq2worApKAP9hAzUdz2zlt@7WGf2myy4UyeVLq6JfVS6tEvbzXZVb4pQ8XOtn3bmTLgJNC6nyqdRo3N892W00KrIsY30ID7Qk4S7h4TzDUbRGGZ4t1muYvvppNFoq3yXm0AtZFomWhT81CrUEKxSJDJLdwYW8kHZJF63/DcmgNz4k0Rm0AZZ4kD2b308f7e7tnySMbdBpjAe7ewnj@Nm9iI6f2fk3Oafx@2h/9/7hMwjw9NH@7vH@pwef7z97CvYeu5hfvgQWz/k7bFryfcGeS69Gb0zLMq2JZTUuJpOL1@yVbTdsIGx/Ytu22x0xz2pYljUEb/5Vhrtle@arV@ZoSBd7/6PvvP/Rf/f@d773/ne@8/53fvCzL3/wHbh/Avf3@Pt7/7aYxefPvvxnv/v@t38HLP8j3H8E909/9uVvfpPf9P3HcP/nkN0fizvkj98SwPqVn335/R//7Mtf/SHc/1LcP7x5/9pPl98/@PbqG8N9/3fX@/nev4P79zgs3@/3fpvb4fuG/9/m/n71h@9/49/z/5@KHxp/5/1v/DE@xMc//eGf/uf33/oPhlH403/z/tvff//tb73/9nfff/sfG@9/89/oqfDjd9//4A/@6g9/76/@8H@i/0/o@Xsf8n//w3/6F//rX/zvf/GH4v4p3P8eTD/9i/8ADPu3f/Aj/H//D/72j36E///5X/3tH/z63/7KvybDb3HD//0v/y1//vWv/ae/@Rff/auffvNvfv2nf/Nbf/BX/8ev/p@/@Z/@@r///b/@H7@Flr/107/6o1/5y2995y@//c//8ltfrnh@Z@3zyw@w//IfwObD8fwQOB@Sro@1@fIXwufvQ415LMAnwN3/5P1v/jIw@G8w9v47P8EZq3Cv@P/E0MnPT/jX/wcMxs00o0sKTHD/@vvvfA9J9D8AieAf0Ou7wceCC//47vwDyPovrgWKWKXFyrNgFOJb0MLYKhZFBRo4b1PIn335z38cRPHLi1AX3CDG76KkWnD7Lsq49z/65vsf/@P3P/qt9z/6FazN1EwxsZtQ9fW9z1AFqtkP8Icecx/iDzx@8QXEP41TX6kaxy/2hXD84osvpOnbJE6RvvsWbL8gK34x7gRuTDj5bsIep6qG/XBjyjduovXbcNRIhjhGGydVYMvXU7JpNo0LjKbYFYdvsAdP0y0yTvFJtug8lfAx/8@NU4nF0Q@/8FQZ30gGEU5EwY1SFqKJT6c@vUhxYlxZ4T23UxpGongzRYYpmE7jU2iRggFiiIPTvTirVCpxDFjh@MAnR61aYIRKPF6BdGNoHibRKCCI6T2CAiEr8SPW2KpMecA4wqv65IhLaHUk64YcL1TuQ4SV6X2GsBA4gX35slItVKZVBPeO0yM@jd8jnBBYJT6tvoPvCsGMY6/S/XeASqESj1cLGCEmkmdPosEzKUuJo7THWVzkAbypi/YuY5/IekHmQxobSDDuG5/xue8dGmTbAffT@JZIDv19I91bRPANikrEwrj7DqmKO1x7RA8AV1U1TWNw48DdDrsLzlMOKk7RwivOIcSJI4gDAgtgQ8yLOOVvnD4g/khl66OveFXiqdnc3JQiVTktH9IQTxxa7aOzEj8W5C1vGpWYnCvKaG3R1G@eOmvzKXU7bN3fgqcO//0NmpEdZ2VCazOKvXtRxuNjn8T5fffuFvsEUk/vuZ3E1HjazWDvOiZ0Ox6XDYi16salFyDdJGBfAvRW0qYVGliKS4kEY1olgm7s8PBQoEYWLypSHLjfSOv4jSMBk8kkAiE0LaElEuKt0ZssNGHQyFW8tU2kOfVGMsPIlKF9U2ZoxcLNER3arWj57t07yCyalVE6gBYlExM0jEyBHMGCrxzt92f@ygEjU5R4c5rpOX5wd4zO9VOYIrEY21IkPn@XI@FfsahRKETRpECeaLEtf75OTpf8TkLqIwxC8DZeIav4jnuHbO/w8eP9JyfDep1JFh24aDWGI7dled46wRzDcLtP7vPp/UYxh2hEajWM@aRkoFiS9kspEpoH948OjkuM00TkUCyApJSpA1iQoqhLkeHw@XZEzGmQ8QQQVz7GZ2me/phRTGOE1bIUaVnYLAGGwz8rS4@97j13Cm35hCwn9Bw20RTqQmXS191SqfJOz@QleNP3hOFeVXxhK5ROnASubW8T0aTqpUrd3miEDM5J1aqYHMR0qXq8fwIBTg6ZbqQ0Bi39y0zeyGQzWSOdy2Xzhp7JFTO5bCENdU0ulTUMvZjJFAvF/JVU/YJNNcRVBXO/0rec7ri3iVNy5NOUHKLHZi2VwJ@RTsMTICb0bL6@sdG/VBHBU2KLS5xbdQWflypS4CtwMekrEvsKWMEFceCEKSZmqx0clsWUIdxCIsbnDcl6Fgq3Ip0CI3Fw0jB8lYdQfKCxH7qlyMY3vjFm1So0stWDB1IEpFSP@dNmVLut9TTio/ZkZJFrl7G2/bmN58Jobdsb9s0ZlM2UJkWurq46AOngAY6p0icP0cbnVYtsmmC@mprS/3/9gldEVavS9rAK/LidHILRBGNmO2mCsQnG7HayCUYbjMXtpA3GSTWtp7aTE6gmpG2@/xLD5Z0VeWxNcbs3bidXPavf0XCBQEWmCAx5W@xnWBXhqrjSwjXbFVwDiDPkY8ql1K603RadRSW1tabbnmneeNbHmfR9d1SJgjYW9R1sPN4T12ZVaqyuDd0h1JlGNh@v6SkQ0XjrhYSRyCbaOA9/aI5xncVONlW6sJ22e6F98fjRw/F4eGTRDP2dTLHU1nBnBVwDvVMoZbP1Wk2W4zWCXcfz7HihVDc2gJEts63Cu@M6Y081CnUI3LZHlUo0upPW9VI6VZCughRLQCtMRlXCcHFEP4H0uhQ8X3JcB8rX1mWc0lnqdDpXpYSZsC/n35J5qfIvIMJV3Ew0L4PPshryF7cTJTaZO15JJbMD1ctli0/EK8lGtiCXa@X5dz4nl@tX0t2B1bZNnJV/mrq8ESiXkq8CP6cp9LbEUw49QcJ5coGj@K5UVZo@VgN5V9@HaqxW3/b3q0JOMgzVSKtpXdXT@L/FYOD/w/0b8DfwCaHShnSCazafgNgDue6wR7g99thlJ65LJ6Hds1orfOz1TJontzdyPe/v4eee6Zxxp/s23ygpcHpo4hEI3sAe91b4eDYc4HJPa/QPBmF/0AQEqQCSh3vwGPVdd5mHPHv2dEUqHwdbEwIx@N6E4P3o4NOHJ6H3yf7u3kMpx@4dPrl/7ZUVnrLs0f6Dk@Azz139oNkAxNf3Hz26/ileEdQAsCd3g2XzvkGXcKLtHWj/3BHGbG5uTKHxOV8DZnvBxE@@2K8knfgLw0yGJbxpsRZfgYsNMtodQ@hler4oSUPmuBcsn2Jtt9838RTIzgZY9kxc8GKhptGnw0ox6gt31G9f2G1rQ3qMa2uKOh51h0hIDwHIYNKipej2WMK9ltp4PiOOHDTxiPkJnoG6whJeaIXGkd3tgdC@cH0PUtM0Gdwfe0F4K3yN11uMeRxkd8Olf9O7FJFQoTTHZqRQvnNHfzoCzq4WUqVS14Imx9D1qvtT4C42Yc@A380RitXNJNvMyrmW/IBpjYi5BUpc1665Xn14xArYn90y05kt0Kl11EtAkTStfARUKJYoMFSnUNWtGaBOnaaSZsZ1ym9ApR9WvWjqyrqyXufy8Z0MVAXjTquMAlxi5dJf/4ufIHdvJUGQRXRZxsnAG7qkke5qFAvZQjFtFBKFYiGT1XPZbEI3EtA0yBchupRe0HOFbFFPFDLFdAaUQXDNFvNShM@0Sm4RSHiXAKzTwnPbtkn91XpVKcIHmdibmKmwiBl8T5hsQRgZT@r2xrTacMuuyEaG6SkGLR@AaLIWizx4sJd68ECW7@EHDq3vpWS5jR/ZQiqVvyfLFrnsFbD@ll0epoDbX8hj/pFK3duT5QkHgDtHynIPP/Zz2HEiyzZ@7O0@eIDxdPDDwPDg7Yy78I@@/5EHbw5@pNPU8yLLrwNw4G@XR5QhTPfxA@NElwfcZQ/cZPlTH59UCiAccX8cwkM/rbu7snzAP3Z30WWPEp7lqH6GH7t0yTJwDZYcWe6CoTuCMivLTTBi@ZHlFphaMxPs8JQ83F7QGZuyPOMEQhLJ8pR8m60zWW749hjNw4cPzd64bXX5NRvxdwtQAxd7Otl/0Pz002a32xzNdvc/PUKXvb2HZmc2GTW7TRGs2YDLhTDgcjaYXb8Ax4NGw@wvdfkMXJxrLo1Zw0LcGuZrwElcXYxk0NgDlz1wWTY@x6HBNQCvTbzuDeB9z2ySi3@RC72nzaZcRkZFFZKOuoUyQ6fOJgZma@SW8Xta2WAsGosmZrVcql4mBzYAZTFVvqIzbmP4NLGlrlzOatNKql6ZVvIGn9jRicmnUyNry4mNwY5ezJY2zB3dyMSnJVxz7HaiLKrqOyym39l6w2JPlB0jnSnJpzs7qlzT6zuGXijl8i@2JrKslPC5k86XwGMqCu1YfCi1fH0nnw0FyefjZtIo5fNK@QrIMYb6tYlipRGLXVjmmaIgutjegiTwE3ZnlE673IlNE9MKx4vNlPK0opf5zlcsdQNWG7dZnLTG7ohD7AK46U6qRGf4ynqxIEP8yWRMUUAykRCB93ze1vOvnZydnHwBMgtasqId@JQfDFkWn58@3NOgaSi@cHtE7QGq6u5I20PBsuDCd@/zrU5ANmoPoZIEbd63w3UgI7ev7U@hdY76vu/gb3qlia2KtJOHC3COoRHMY8ZltGXa78JpWQx3j7TbzKxUwWS2WYywYqZyQdVzo1qtNCoDfgxvNQj1GaOtFedgDjyOe7C4l4Jf4toI4dCopK7Kzco0MgU4jQpT9ZcDt/3SiLfKbdw08l7lHgYuN@DdLFsVCw8jliNyubPjVBibOJ7ZsZ5aI1yqfnC4CXUQLpiIdZilbLJTOrp4D7XpK7U6Ys4csyeTQcxUq01l0Sr0iaSJfc1P8iWt4MER76typ8JiL5Tya/gcbbJYW7un7GTK7dg91lDAJvWy87LDDJbLlOk0txhCgkJEtKEjgZVK9TPQbzjgs1IJEBF5fAYwMSYAa7fJwVSG9lW5VemzmMqmTCHyZMrdSg1Dv8XHtirLdVWtva1LVVV9LlWhnJZnEbPiTZq00zBLNXUjlStPwU7PZ8o9yFjzxbQ8qgwnI6vch0/RKcIXKpllICdQDcC8eRt7/8vfVLbVbIXblQnU2z6oFA2tUZmWHdy7BFiikq6AQ7yWSSWyBajvs/kEVMgGKAC5RDqRSah5tIXaGJqNYKmDIhDrx2TG5ERqmtL0hG7pCSj9L@32S6YkzmKgjRDJ4GPs7uNJyGADmYRcSZ/wNpkSN7b6DHLBZea2SmwKkqKMCQOa99jQTvQQ1JFl9imEoqgsvRXrb8bQz@bJZLhfq5dK@9Ph18Appr7eycXzqfgbRSnHNpSKZ72WqmWpilKFUj3cAJ4V/UXMmwxqkMfjTT1vlGq1JqYwn0qkU2lInt14292Wq3I9kdrI6ZBDV4z0GMYFBtdl5trI3K6BOjUeK870olGWNJoaQTHqMaO4aoWLIuGkPAFQGgphhxRmsVPZX6oXi0bzRjSqRMvYs7whiw5BkHD8hHIQtdE7@o4M@pNckosGepgLSlqNlQqrUFcSNrRZpihFLqWry6ttaHQmaY4cKIlsg0yqVr0rRUqMgR53Kvb7SG4w9rFT7@Lb1Rf8fYqzcwGuRHuP1VidJsRYNraU2Oe48nSHRQExczSoGUa6XjPyUL@BzPS9GoZexn7zCE4D1qpAee8S8NuOV3HRxmdsNjPjqk/ZO4x145sSJTpyney7ld3u0W7Z/9rDrrtTSZblclSOXEYj0Sv4SZG7tFLE4CtFWCS0VoTPLm1ZQJ93EZIYbO/S77gp4QkYMbPE5UOtrrx7YvcvC2mVt/pBYF1dRTaTlCNiwn35s5dGFvLIcf0Z@ND6QY0aqq5sFvsdI8mXQ@8bRiH9@ODQuT96YDE@Ab@QacjVCEvpKs5nL5eEbZZPwJWLBUM2zhIRdjdSjrAzNaqXaJI@Gx4XX@RfFF48fnb47PCBFDndeLvhYp8088nC3jlf/Rp4jKYzUcZOK5FpJVMWc6CqVVXfNnArnTzDY@Y7ek5Nva1y9q2SQ84Al/e//MPMdLsA3wZoryXIwmzcqFb1LYMpkeH7L38ft1C43P989xGLeuaM/d2f/NjI/92f/CuaWRS9KnvUAZqPgE806rl85PJyeHl5BRd3y0bqEY5UJq@AmXe265H5OoBS0jS38vGMcdcpJ4VfPa8rEU@NiCGFfDbivRVORqoATn6fP1nJOcyCyP6RnTX0u9vIFHqwfIjNh5YtrwhcUXj88i1j8NGqtrtd2yBTMslK71S2/U7dZu@wz/ydusFeVqo4zqvjoiO/l3irWq0iFBatxpNbUWZkwa12Va7HGfUzQ1PwhbXlbJ0ucvTpBisWHbC3vC0xKnG65UF7b8uhn7XlefDpf1lbrzwm47hJMtlu094y2xbLViH/t5KAzqny/pd/0zByf/cnv/a28bbxhQEtt2IxpxuRn@s//zl4WLPa3W92UR86LktHQ9BcYyuORNZa0FLEc7I7jPv3G2/YXEOdwe460FrHL@kc9RzKmgbfQqkdI29buBg2QVozbXCilCUp0C5JKx51WwmCwbZwu3oom9Kl9BV0gsqUVUBcSl@ZgwKLAVSfbqvh9SejIU2uj1E4vZ5gdyAIxPAV3J5qgxbxCpmrgphKbt0MylH2iGqkE7GB5Xm42RXUItJXIIjYWgxP4TVxvTn6tB0Q8hp6ITzJoV2DuOsQd58HaJBtjFLPPSQYx44HckBzlr4CygBRwQYdgdnb4KEMguUrQABIQ0wAtutsm6UVdmnH4@X5TlpXOE8Zt1cz/bWuEgZDaG1cW@0HLqM/sAKNHQ@zQb4QOQzqWcjSB8Jh8HHUCuj8GJy@UOmixegfDApg0cYvMUoau3NnjlWlYrcVRilC@Gf2EPukKB@c5bgCML@99Em7JCcY7lFW9m0DtgOKxwld4DqVb05WDgVlMn5eSRL8P5hpkSOvZRU5lDEBIr94qWgBySAwkp3nYYttV5hu5BUWIN8C3FuEFG2LFTQCT6efaMYXvuMVYPjziL9VNEifk3A/n@Db64udGVR7E9ynF7e84cJALFLmm9qgFDsY@6GDUJAUu0@@O/YIGig0juvvkBVL6woGm@8oRnjQzGMjw3AKcFbBF4VC3wzeJu4FJeLZoP0sWi5kqDd0Hdo8ija6wNnVwBEgo8QePBztiXOB@7qLvKHAYYw82n8HOR8xps2w6EA8CosDo80RtGJ92iSY1dVYa9BmRpHFiNForyAnAKdQIEK4Cdou0rjZtwaA0rFlMdw/ySslk13QiiZN2jDpsQ181XtgQ1XieElx9mDywj6zkye4L63qdkCFFsvPI6hIYfHjY7Bic6K@656xvn1m8e7b2MLifY@Bvg9KawIoO7@BsCXsKTbSCZYC5wT3BXceXnluLCRCYTdiM@XmO61vxBqYo2@pTrJHeK7guemE6EvXW0k0cb2Z52//QZtYwLcWiFxLLPyvRHHNcbCjhSQ2MqnQHhoaduEPY9Dg9DcAQSPo4tY5w8aqhHUMCM2Wv5QeSzGk9itUAVDZg5KFe4GNRyXcAAIwGbVjLSh6QsA77BOWNiT0yHdnETupAAzM@soidHCDoJgOb9yGjNH4si2QK1A6B21ww6XHgv0wvM/daKZ92ubszTYEOKx0KK4K48XC/8iGPrB0ID9T0jfAMQcYLsFkIybHAWxcVmQOOgh/PTjndolkSYndhJRgCEGQGqCQquAfPMpCG7BL4HDP9PgunWLXsIuLC422r5uMbM3ycFNyD09TTQ67NujEbnJsDYbi@Ccbj/0TcOcmlZ9FgGfs7kzpdNvinRl/S1LHq4gZE7Fox4ti5XiOe253B7TtDe434xFDPbBpv/5WTEzy4Pxn1BOXPv@VkP/UQvQKgTCGYKaJWaKVAGCJZuss0blol4XDORVIAA65aPmWuGXkyP8YeL7JHnYCH@6Y1jL4383@GQ1hAiSZd53Oo@Yp9H3O/E/xPbSnEMixLtjuaGTOYuSuoG9k4NiM1B42g2qfXMAI1Qy75PsX2tParL4QfBoEh0rNb/KwEe5pI12uB8o3s0T3KXefgvuUu0/nkfrR1qZ1rpKh1RUmB7ket0LzfSKYme/nim/8OHchyKBYM52DQJ@zBbsruFsVCu3Tm39BPlZ8xgCeGALBrViy9uK0dlp3POtiqx5PdoHZZSIE5DiArtWJphftwIzU75/3h663YOXgDnhQKwm80arVE9zAeQXTGGQQMQanl42blnUHYuSdKwQiwQAB9TBwRNVgdxyzlXKweyo5AuPU5DmNOWI1gUydtC/hJOxAXeKk54QNA6qHAKF9kCRAE1yYX3L4ERS@dHg@wpO2fb8q7Zo/wM1zovUoUPJaUeGypkyZFMJKVX00geyorlauJ8V3h6yoXXMKJfNK5H8Y/Y2PRr8D5WI59sSwvMIoS@GiglPIQIUQxYWoyqqVUL4CBskts2@NoOba5/qpqK0hmq2k38zg8WASvAs8VzMWyvyWwvOHVpfJjlwKWGFWqUASZxVeLHm58EnKCR4E80Swmc8IIjwXIAAjtTSYJYJNw8GmlQoXHGy6IthFCMkpITnlQbjv6Qok6yIYtJ6CA5kxe@qgneKENRng6bwaBTVoKDM8XBNHql/hxl44SininMsc4gLBQ6hiI5@16ktjr4WQDgmtawCQEW8AaPPTrErSdYGnq8FXIKM4KX0Zxb8EG3BZAQxGIrjMN7@MBUxGbWBQ@OU41QNQduV4TZJ16tfFX4rfcsK39G/9pmVq0ae@aJlKXPv9g1jWkbKhAhrSPvRUBgUytmSeiWPIF3SOCB782HNBq2teuCy2RNkG@6R/gnmy2XebyYGJs0PwjJvgXHPFbz/gmAi7O3TH5tjNZEq80WQT2y2Ln7cZ7K7jQtMkvOkt6Hpt1/Kc6BgyteV2HduzEniSOlfZLZqrwHczl8J6sjC6niSJPkjejEXQnK9Q1W008NS9RiOGc9CUUjDXlaakIXtGoxK2f8EUCg/iSQA9HMbc5iurNVZuh4n7M4tgJ3brLHY4FI5RiGSXgQxrgf4Prj3QYJjnzluOtFMsqtLNcYz2zO@5A7cLWt/E0yQMfQ38wRw2ImQOh4RLgpnYpC2FdummUhJrJUxFBP3so4Oyz4yYqQThjUUAC8RIsNF1GiNlR0uia6yMjgfz4zv@eHyPw/ger8eXWuHXceZN8wp3/Lio07E5BPA4RyN9OxqYdJBb7RvoLKASWKNexQN8MIptmn3VRkx3weuu8K51gD8SwZcHXwHin6@i//oM9IPvf2j2mXgU6fEM5M0AJwXG6DQDzx/cjIH3A0WRIkuiC1j7/gfGBX7xIJkHqEKAGkuCy8FNLqFgDqHZ7QVbr/uAb@F5nER1g@9pZlWFOy7BaXSeYGfG6iy632hbfXNmtWPCZyIE10/xETTYSF59WMJR0JHQc3lbLwZ1lxK4QjWOROeeSitYxkycK8pqtuJe7IB7qKecMDxYTT90vyGasYuvwnuroR0QjeKGa865jd2fw9lwxvdR7vNDKIQc5fUPz0lcQ387QYAOYhuZxDxaZZ34PIoFSfqAGiHwqy0mGbc59SHiDqI38/DjSHR7SiFzQ4Eqfi5Li2cCLM9xe12Oh7jC50k@bvRhLHkb030wz4VYjQObi7C9j6tCbkDG@RitViwMkduszTHXuSET0I766ZwVtUpjiUANQpKkG9vU3Cb9QpGwZXwAb@xw@hzeCLBrjRucofy0YZ@WOB2GkcvAHIa0FmEDSjpACVGRk1ygEfIl@WbwfnkVxNlaGWfrRpythTiDErAYZciT1FqIUuQCZs@6LOhbnfEK6YxO2HaG1zqxDZfjmiPsrbiM2tGSnWDR82gJBHLUipb2YyCUo@1o6T4ZvGjpmAxn0dJnYJiXrejbaMkvFuhhBJ9kuIv2QoTjdyta2ospV9LYPLM8P14tWgryFPzs8E@iCJAC0w1aIw6xOa5I5nhkQcVGSmWCIcd4CWw@UT9Mgu4U/PkpH3RaADpiH@cWeWZxpi9UGqEag8cD1Ya/G/WSklwStfn@4QOazxR4wWji0MYLhyHwoIZHoovCiCOGrjSiAW9AEOVmaTlGLFSTfSA6InbgUMrkxfiJehrpA@0YudfAc30eCR3tIsL7@bUIgmfgh@GJgVfheQMdPzrCCMdklSVoIVFfRtckCvN6EReR@@Ecor7uRU94lq/vhecSgQ3JdNDhaHAOIxu6w0UmIVecF2@Hw1CnHC@UyL3XgpFUECVzhTNZi5ShYAgXfmVdckLhELUFEYSOtVSdl7KgXiBZjE5zWRfSVHnhAxRCMgdKuNU6o2Nz7gsj@ePiJkF1xapqyA/LoyTJtSgmIbCGmwFNzDGPPWi87uMWQR/XfPVDTrGvJYYAQiGDWLh8dT9Cf3e5/u4r1D4RrkWwTLFeXpXeVK/X1rLXMO/Po72ZgeiYYPeVpcpREMOc5NA6CGnm63jthoqPUz64ks8jDaBf0/Z9sgVtglvodr1twWGhljA6X7Q8M8DyzFhNqJsaSf9c85UWDWMScHjCA0znSVuPK0/4sixGF@rfNvsfncGjxQwOZx7CowSMrpGcl/LRxKFZLvOyDWKb26BI1UuMC3IaLg2yeW4J4p6GboNhW7A4bBzdP3zy6OtQ6ebzeUXU0bM5flhqsa81qMc5ZJocHdQHS5otRgJPwsDBbuyOp3OzN04d@YYs4cIalAETYvHZT5RxRciykDy/VnYhHPcboqiAdTYvBuaCVEJVx8Qq2xZ0HQNBrHFsyxRAfPUW6J2g1ppCZz40GnhWcqNB1VejgZOXGg1Ri2HW@CPiys8jG8mJN6KzGvmBJReSRKv42f1D9vzh7gk7ebjPHjzb@4x9/fAZe7775ARXYz99du/RwR6De//J8T6TFqZH4uFO2KAEut63WhYewoc7qWUYQd5zhzMud2J7Crc/NgfsoduycJhq2zMHd3v8Q3OscZWH2ofm6Az7MG06wGtgj3G@BZ0@Bc1YVG7atO4O5/Iz8NuENu0A27wDt213bPArYdt3aFuev/yL9W3IQZC3/vrYBFeS8KApmjpER8LhDKwLCG6Cfxy7ATAmn39Fx1HbHg9gtTUmCBdcH03Bk/2jx8cM1/vvHT65f3BycPjkmD04PILPp18/ePIp0PPg@OTo4N4zdCKPjw/vHzw42NslC45ASmO44v7VxBuvRUFD70SV1hmOfNOp48HXYq83avDswqQViB6LThyUPrbZt99Y7WhZmniovuCqRxoqYLHN3aNPP4c6n1mvcYTTHwqm@QfyM48OPNtMsW2KDQpLFcpbWRRXqPZUXaHxiMGM4fkHVpkW18fInGA@cJrE07YtJu/hHBXs@@Zr8Kks@6Ahog2AjaD8CSsVRueWRKOJbQJZhdhafRd3UeSx8UmE4gOD3vWnmpQlopiYK4NAcb3CgYP9QXo5sAC@BwtDRDsecQ8sHVhwDyzDLVAVPcC5IywrfEzGhxMUzyzHLV4Nhg9oWJjlA4t7JrViCwInnm@UpSYLzn3CHQn6dDoN7@WhU/NMr2XbFMQj/3hyS7/PC4bFzwwDmciHEmluG/iUQdh0cKhBTHvjp2uiK3ADzhMyO2OPxSqKxk5wcpDl2PxcoG7fdPgUqPnUHeI9VsA9Zypimq0dnKdDK0CGLjEgnuW1iEcQ7r7QCq0PDQch792I0RRzJOlMO38K2m0I3LuBwC8CBgCpCy2dFtVUtNAUwbgdwcoxzwWOxH7bd2H/wM7tSctaCCBmbcVe2W/eKILIiYV2kj9PkbCDLHpjjUCtpKHMjjuCMk5ilU4gQSnY6rnDsc3zMLaYAhpxomoOfGPFBrG9rFQXYkM6XI/RcZ1QpE3g4hWxNoEpPyRW4ng@dh6Ir/lxlMD5UAnzeXeIjtnEU7fnY2cJHES6sLD7BRRhGivHzs/ZmDDh@qc0lx3vGJ5oV6hU7987Vd@9TOCxdlws8JMk/UmHeANjYlxQPGicjyYsjlDvEiXNP47ImzQxtJiDJ6QllnIfGLQDeza06@42yoEbn2580x7XyFy3J8u3bys8lIqSSRwu6vVic@mWYDU/ygSFqTMxBSQkOwFZkPUx3yZBMAN5fRfXxWAulIEiDsoRbLdfO@xHiBA/dc1JBySLOHNRZHcAX2FVmlExP4IWV7aE8yP5InavEq8qyfmEEhYiZ8wX0Qkfsq4ooWkpVF/dAHd/PTiQ3x8OrrAWO149fBS0@2uhfRRuanw1LF4thWB9ONh3a8Dyyu0XAgtpT6wGzCvJm9ACTg@YM7EZCWbTro/x5Y28o7IHYLDuxR6UAGgotolDQ9T@nsUxHkAJg5krRMcn9/ePjpjM2ycQFuQeNhnaQgwi7A32dD7b1nZI2GmB0hQ0lgPlybdZmNHmX@sK81LirRAVQgdJCHoEwmJ@2HLHnnKpJ2oWUiFo9j0JRJ9yi9hd@jLIqwnAV9AGBGTnmRZKoLQ0mRFe@dheeBK4oFuC68bhOfw0w5rX3XiS4WgWBhSeE2R2cWXJ8vx7zvXjkh8PV7BwMxxMcBs0aahvoJ1wDBEPwaOmLebg/1PctW61kSTp39RTpEvYqEBXbLCNEG4BwtYsBg8Xu30EVgupJGtaSGqVAKlt9szuj32B3f/7CPsq8w7za59iNr6IzKqsQmD38Z4zPseoqjIzMjIy8ha3fKBbTJfCyF422ClDOxh@FeI77B9nKGYk2YTLXtia1vXmWKMm@@NFs81hg0QsA01YeupEsWimBDPF85dNu0O9aNFLx5cg2mTibrufbK6g4ue3pfC29XS0TpbDDbk91hYZm7rB8hzSWQ27dH@mx7CFXk9OD8mqaLZ9sKrs/09VskrEajI0n9sYk0iQ19fWnn4LdrIVpnj2R2HLGpKcPyeXIzrfRyCDWcDifeLc2kHGpEcM8ADpxLTeDJhEQdrqzFlTYm3nxcjGj3ARuRAhg1jhuC4wWaunpgnc5kOXFcmGzlnutMEawmFDZdTcof7tw9VhQv5mfY/@eH0y2JAJpoO3sMp/OxwHfuSVZ0VRsT7BfzX@zR@PB5xN/JkuASXNbkwPOtuxt50YvEqrkMj6NrslHe2dJGa3GSNr4EpYvJjDDaGQ7pWS4r1ssWQ3da@2X1XLHMOvE5NFumPXs@aeR73BQwjwHMxyCSwf7MP3ONig/4RDxoAkMrE3X5pp430TN6YI7ZrrfH@LNgvVc2sx2fudoNUcIKRHxn0cKDfzhAqyFLZ6uOfNk6wXSrHyhFwwGqSpVMbN5lwuSt8g0AWkOAjpTXy3Fix4ahhLyQfudW/miy8K6y8dbt0gM8lc1l@eZ5ZbZVfR4tscXAZX45v2r93h5@uO6qvRXy6mrdnvvym19kw9pbpWn0j81uJ6Oc/BL5/T3xfqZYE5VyP4imPRnrlK5eQuOaWWVHQOLz1Sco8aH5o34CGR4FK1fGm4EC52k/Jlff28PCgXSpf1wXkJTn6TlfJkpbiSxocntIrSHCOa@frkHGuqLXX1B9cKV4zyVXDaNUSxawh9edsc94b7lYPXMWkcNgAQgWlbbxaoy@2gC7Bmg@9JbuDfpLWYLKPAsQ42SM4CewUV4dPO8mSIY9o9wox6JUO72WDKf2ees1DIXY0mQ04xYfrAWupr76uzYNyYCixRoCz1ngnmx5eiB9MoTxqKIfk6EyvqbFG2a0X4TnoWiDpK8nTonrkufAqBqPblqp87Qc5vtj4DCVyH@5WLqc1NvhyXWC3IsRQPphzNMTtMFM7xCAUI/YxY24AqeOcesNuHQ83HexEP8oVlVBP2k2EDeYd3ikiB@bf6wv5NXH6TCCCEX5A9V06LOPXOizaS4jvIwgVEI4sf/KFmgFuldMoCGgvYUl85As6W4kwjVKvJRN8XbkBOoRX90y3IFvntTjPC/J5kZ5Kwnlq/BaAldyknbeGnHxVLW8WyppjJbJFi4ZvUgKSLjkdvfRpWM7Xj9/uEtNBiISIHHtm/V9e/EtYf1FHneYi8pGfvpGdj6TlJF6SiXDla4KNMG3YmN/Ulyner3Chb5k5dZcWblxz1dCtHW5Iob@mhvEFuMmz0osxbYVcKV4YJm7GErJXyaU7vS8qjWJmQwcP0uqRr/l7VPR9iGcv7U7x@/Dq6g3w2ntW2JgkuzQ16/VeyaIUpYDOXqKmUFEd/M9vJoNQ@mHo6oR0c5Pw8bLfKEZSVoplxeMy4W5s/uTm9yXiVTqIhXox3BtacMWJRietcYcJN2WGR6uHkRxYIhglGU2bkbpnCM114ZoFFrkemWvGCvDPAqWnJIV6GX@RX/DGDPY6cyZean7ggmE@l8eLdHCcQT7qP3Plkis8mcBeRj7pRD6wiUd2zJMT5k8SBJQUO6/TFB7sDMfijcJ6wJwozU9yhe5iiKR1lKBr2va8LkXjr/CO/7Lxu0h571PenqoJjRpO9sJyYg/vEDyYBYjtxLJrgajTqQ@vIG74bdqHWgUJW16BuiSBaK3vOqcGyR/Jn8KQd0qlQTh0C8g0MRKKE4KrbhTMZPGCHN5haIXHpTXJOZTATgQaNmaer4mbuq6tAtKZ02u/aSEjPyegBpYNRs@XnHNqjBbT7caSpHRnfWp4OvxFED6MlbcNx/nzVa/268xr63OfFwtOiRbJrrQ4u5J4@ixysiEgmYbVA29i14jPHsXTDLdENZwEwo/ax0L8n3vSv/cHAdyq0YnDGgDatgT@@9ts5xznyQyUw4IKVoZmEH/bwatwS4Q5tuprEjPASDjKiDiMOwy/WZ1EXt1hXlnGgtIq0zdTV1702CGg8TjpDaIdZYYEwAUIPFLr0J0SUZU/FUWLds8aF9y6XEEQRNRDnxNJNhGQYDCe9FvUMS7KcPoESNUhU2aCdwITqa/WbcA7OzUMA7jERBQwCRpX0EA6OVpr/IRyUbpjRsTdNz@Rp9hvyWKHh7o97NPtGBOZe4WIW7tTBJ29qx@r4cO/kQ@Woquj53dHh@9pudVdtf2QdNxTlHNZWvTncp9kl1KaL1vyQPriVYyrpcoJTOfioqj@/O6oeH6vDI1V7@26/RtAI/FHl4KRWPc6o2sHO/ukua98Jgjo4PFH7tbe1E8p2cpjhWk0xJyqnDvfU2@rRzht6rWzX9msnH7nGvdrJASqDVr@i3lWOTmo7p/uVI/Xu9Ojd4XFVoWHObu14Z79Se1vdzVH9VKeqvq8enKjjN5X9/URDDz8cVI8UGwlYrdyuEpaVbTrCoiZu527tqLpzggZFTztEPEJwP6OO31V3anio/lyl5lSOPmY00OPqn08pEyWq3crbymtqnJP@BlWoX3ZOj6qIfwRKHJ9uH5/UTk5Pqur14eEu0/q4evS@tlM9Liln//CYCXZ6XM0o3DHHVRMMohal0/P26XGN6VY7OKE14/Qd7B086uQPRBjCskJFd5nAMINAa4lIh0cfARV04A7IqA9vqvT9CDRlalVABVhU7JzY2ahCIuKJ3Ux1UH29X3tdPdipIvkQYD7UjqsedVjtGBlqMMj4SKxDlZ5yq9FPhJc8ErM6hnMz3J2qtqcqu@9rwFznJg44rmluYbLtvNE0zyEariVE6Q0hM2he2oKVzt1P1z6CS96VyMyX0YQRk3YOd6u0IutgVW6UcEqrzotEKCU7jVaaMJFeYyFr2v7FVbfRG3SG8DENi4ng4zLoZnBZi4c7K86cB@7E0PIVLpBKNRrvKw066B43Gl7me0rG0PhWCS0GfyiXp9uIuPs4eUPws7EhdN@MEWrriVZ0sqEeFBDIKdR/IqZvzUvfU/l829fF4LwPwEZ0FIja5DNUKTQ1srMjLtaIqmTJBL/3NDtwwbQBn2s1ICeFZSRnGgb0Z/A1epHFwfpAs7OIu/J5HGIZjd7vvqlGKuGQCPxHRyTodbjKXOD7v3bTBbs6nPlz3eGwnfY8U4bzTugc2E173yh@4XcTxbPJ8owsq511GP3AnLt5CxPqnzXJlO6X3JhblsafxoR/PIONxHyA1JSrYmG1Flqmn0hxWCRllA5tAfcK7mTs@d5Wfq59wGmusPqslPj@JvwuYwv2gghCSwtencud88@bc8lAA4xjcRBJejpCRj5vlTH2JmHmG8r4GZluem1Y/tBa/dnndZ1IQhvZq2bfrhOr8bg3tbGnefj1UeXt9uneHk2dwPbZi7Xn6yUnDLv1c0Z@P6IejhTLUcdGtI7TPo2TrFGyQxsfHilWLO2I/ZmB83lkRIh102n8EXEeQruNuCUTJjI0N8AtMwOY6Lk@6OAqDsDxyDH8OndkagZIx5rqoTWXzSlv8Zu0V2Ie0MYs/Rn32hR/ADsc/maIhw3SDKRZjGPnEufS6YLnPXfPmIry4YYD9yBLzjV8LGHcQhqwqIvtZ@Fdy2@at61eDMSUEeOVu51LEhKPklgoY1cxkJH9juOMaAEwRw@jLz9rfqPHjzrAHYe7awaTyuSYyLgXloScOhJG60bXNeTzrTJ10ZMnYU2bClJ@TyPFY0@Lk8PAINZoYFRwawhsfOOAS2EckWSVbAH705KnvginIngH4JQ0x@p34tx5zdFQSiZ@iH43USmUwAqDnAjVbsI6HJPlYxjHwpAzRqYfogfD/yfSZA78TTpxEvSIWlYQwO@iJEMVWtHxlYnSuzGKBku7EVHT/vQxAnNrd8znsGFaezMV/xoige6dmfnwkcMedtJzCAAmh2DDHr@hSdrnJh2dfnI9XRx6kkHrcpRWeq0wS8UduNn18wxvuzJGt4IXT3kia7Iq3Kei6ic5uF3wqKcjU@Iorx4HroDzTPyP/DILQMIBz1z6WaxWk5xV0KPMzAM61JK14LTDiEm0Lb29V2u3rKwQmbG5X2u@DKEI9BbwudtOvvtjqMQ8Nx5xkVdidcJR8BAPHMdkLD46ZN0FG2L2fcB53GZhCK4HmdxggegLdA7VF0FT6cdsKIJKIqvDKM4gplsvR6TlZfUmxJ4lk@DQEPvTgQSi90WqZXLkJMCHxtB2l8@pt80Zodz/vmYLi@WXj4cZ2C6iMhFL6PK4CqU1HI5p69hEuwnHTG/m5dQHLXTwB8HVWMcvpPWsN9YSCbPpp2qwbZLTOy8zEgOeUQt6E3grtHPMH9ykSx8WohKeZJpdV2liXsOjW0bo2JuuFFV6M0rZJJpwWFIm4qZaV1@/Si4hqA4Z6jMFe0F4uGCbTa4Heodw@N0Mx79i7ccWaND222FkUgskywKlk2oDjvHYmkjTR8OAJRrUFZCAhJQoiiAtNFSlNfq5Zidt1@RG0TERu5Rb8sfrCZnUWEtRRRHj6tqJ@daz1Jmg0qoODRoGCy2urjEq8w5ct/cexjhaaFxtrdyzQTilbMgmovzYbB3xJPNm@PQRT1rIX34cYPTQF@i49RYUCGPPCr3q3XmO8YNNwYeeP27bMlHaybSbI4jf@OgzHDAvGtGhDvvXak4Cf0YngFa@N80zjEb6T8PPg8bOsN/s9oa9Jp3TEMZ9KjMeHmf8iA7rjoc3Ad/ywwltK1N7Fj1LfBkJw4b3UC9ZskJzBRN/lLbNFCbjWeWzhIlgyTmMAKPbIpm/R8kYaWGZZ2tRISfuf8r2eEWvdG/Zp8V5hUWjDwB6gttKWFCID@mEHZMs59PSnQwXD2WwcLxQWdX07rHYi2H8kkjEapgYxgaZO2YJdiNwMrsX43p7mmlzDMIxAi35uz6unAnS/DnTxL28NIu8gqXAhiq@KFhFRYsyRRxCPMzuJ/fq838y9oTAD6BffDqPW@YxAk9xHRNtKZDzio4ySriweWCP52ieiWkW63VpFerHgDamSajx5Nl91GDLH9oU6TB7d7gSIzJNBx9cHJdu0JTTmHlYVJbUksdxO7AFqUzShfsZ1v@W/SwPfihxRXKGiWlHQ05bSN9HqhZRCVeQJsxrbZQlpvK3R8zq6vf2WoKA5XkmZ9ZVu2nX7FzYA6Un6yvUWsMxTcZugnra1GMpmAxHS99JvXvnjrmR2ebRuuV53zQEFmYr02K53GbSlmd4nJWcJD4JpolTjC3NiIdwfOXnkM2TRJyWGxhv5cbsG3S4j2aR3VS4qIT93Zaxj0XxGha9ZqEJhxTjjiClpfB7vUENb9w/g2iYcrxq8IzRwJTRmMmjBSpBppBK308h5j6Ne4IebaIc6m0T7ez@uZeoSSM5E/LUJMWCXIKeCNwOp02al0YdGF8gTJzscMNJKtxwTjMzVuUVsxcIMowEAYhdsZ@N5FAiwY06K8FHfDtAJ92AtVARMxE9bdkWDmHQ/5BgHJVfC3e0xUNjli2elwTSNIREpwrO9RAk429Or/XGlKHcIQUN8TmkCFt0Z276/P2t@tG2UD6CIKU5WVv6FjJojKdWCBv6Yyc1ptgDR1XpkrERFR8IDZ4aaCzQKaXb9@W4it1fbywcD@sGPYzoACGf0/hZ0SUQznu9EFIbRabtGbJ4mtwy2jyV3ZIiEUPJO8ivh6JsdfngSgB8wZjKl4sEAWFNGXsoBTj0js15MUR1H1HBchHDkj5yVNTIznNOOoiqMzxbs3IU5uV4acPIzgVCG4v5eSJEaM8yP0sEhRa6ubhYOZ7Pb0@UgzbEhveF4tQVulfiNAx7TgjItxAXvGhGqRdVpqA5mBOfrXmxxJC/OfVlwUotJFOJPiGG9WwxmfqiEEuNVbu6Gi8aK0n08OxaY4lECs9GOJwVfuwfu6bYIc9Dm1DrkBHbZWj7bNwSTadMOrfl/hKoTXbKNnsMA8/2DDfHr4ZcsRILyv5wAHa1xCoDxG7/4dYay1SDib4rgOPSGWeXtBwIecfqYqlHs3DSNZH2wgAF5kw77Kj3J3t7sbCvFzNjaHTpj9cKhQKY@MIOfm9sqyFK6g3z8dz5zlW/nx/d/Gn8/iLPc7/v85UAG@YE7VOX0KAIcsNxV26GAA6UFbmz2pEVZ/2rTse@ggEaSnQedZvk1NEQFC9AvdDo5f0JC4AYpF5gf0ED0b5fVDj6bpqy0dRQjBqKSsMk@No12jMiDz50YJ8daqoYGCZmY81E65ZX3vqCFQQ3m3Bncfhi70tknuy@8fv9YUZ9wD3BiBSwcJsssLdnFyhIFmgY2bv3KuB4tBnlX/f6ll8xsti8DnBmYTL3TJi48IiNf@R3q9NR2q1/cmlZoSavoJkriE@dUW7X9XSw@O8AK3xIaH9X7svmKN1iOiUz01KvR3D0RBg9LWbmnn1iWTyWiWmafTs3iDof3RwHa6Cme7wXMLHsuXu5JfdkD4nrnk2LHdCwIDA0Toi58n0l4Gr2z5sWryedzvfNinwNgHTsH5oR5SaUH5sQWQfAI1APP6Inomj/S5aG9V4ioIhscHBZx915BwUaKOA4j1vl327SlUpFLY5WVlSlsk0P2ayqbFfULj5sb6tdet/G@5Py6tpaSebcXe8Lfdw2H2/VNsFgCedK6/N4l14prQy/MVhro4sX8@XFTGmxUd7cKgX5emUbbv309Pd/@4@///t/5iv65b/xss0v9U9hplwul19sfVl8clvCe333fGnxor44Ol/qlsBl/@Co4cPaJNuMzEdz4wsnJauA9ZXtSM05m6PP6KLK3Op32Rz/SrPLhkq1gnxKfw3k5iieY1Mt3/ruw4/ygo7w5tKB5FGekEgR0BnE8dQ7LR8GeLTeECUJF9iBSnnRrRjBPcLBhBlCrUpKR@LhPeu1D5@WKJICfHFpxcr2BoE/gAT8mve80jzHadJvb9LQ/Jv/9Dbobg@navksrZYLajmjll2Xf4rrL@mrt5jvwTtXstFxwHUzlBKpFmBmqIIeb/T4/MB37STI7TiLfGUPIJkwFZxZvOAy4emPnWXkwrWg6yzg0kwlIhJWMqFI6svi4Ja65QvluHVjrja8UWjoUwxXZmlUwv7FFqgZiCFAVPOlEGRjSFVC08ceyXjKmy@6rx2@TYgBg6xHr/d43OMDrUWLA23zHDtL4ZojNp@Xr1gbS@IMzWgjReqPEGCFihwnC@xJuJRacsTK22olN1O8sO32aeYTW4eZPzG26VLoX5XFBGLNbRNucaD9WrQht6hXlNsL1StWVW7S9ls5VpHLq/6kN9LuClw7BtSXsLZbGUnoUQYkcCRm/8bdEcaCAhMpKtEtclnWTLWHaLqMhIF2TacO9nKiObKIkP@UprH9NTG2vTx7iRh2EB5gpEJTvk6z1w901JUxE7vbHF/gdsBmhy9Um4jejOV5uCY1gfGwEyKdY8hsch6NZ2pKajRudi@bGZU6GJ6Mm7MaLVu085m0ch61ECGYgAQGn656XvMMwtIi3SVMkbApbDmEywv6M309mvStG/qcoEvNUNBhVzAIYuzElPS/xvoqQceIq/9AJ9go35m8Q22knmJ55oWlkYbk2m4zPMzuDB3H1GCPnXDguI6gGo5Mwwu60BUW2ktW/NJM3keMAF23q70AtSvC@kvUj9Wp6w@ascVp1HeMo3@@pGRdxHjmqyjFGskxN58WoxvvgBXtIz/Fo0DI2mTCGTkL6fTCWaCvc0vZ6wgH@Q5t8fNN1QsvoOMLzNgzRJ0OejJZJlao6A6MnKqx5T9B6PSbXcJvdtOcgRXPUulXj/Je/dPZ4Hw5fTb4eva7x5joKdmsslmV0spsM2PpsUIrYz4TezVWaYEJNXg2iGc4GyjxYbFIQIjk0/VP@fOveULoLIU75c9SQpBYlwGT/MP15QE@fwfNVByLfMpZ8JY90/npV0VP0drKv@hD@eDJL2FhDpUspqdzzrhDoNhP97crcTkJ8i9WC89Wi8/oJNT1p9mxf4X1NhtcXfhT2koEOM7S0nP2e4wbYoS4nQbNEn2cUjvlWhPxPQm0k5KeQvUw53qckK2oTE54gvITlTlcKlxcvDBPE8pHHPgziljO5OVYUGI6aHFfGutnMLxEPc0A81rSO0Q4ElYGYiPCItQsIJvLV@7jUM8MlyX2c8qpHcRuZSDUvfmUtVoMhoOs3qx5uaUSNtHwmum/KLwoJMfonSEaG6GLejO19EgVt149/9t/Hf6WmqS2VvMfxvQ7Sf2WWn@Rkkd6oLen5u06tZXaRLb129QsT2dgenz@t/@h8lt/IjhImW3Sn601A2t9ltrKlrnI19TWOj0UV1ep3v/961@pDYtyYsNdrIuNjGLESoYiO80B8y6lqxpaKcfSpWhaYccswBALQzqb0wsMo6arLwospktpq4prX0e@MvYoeolnw6wJmwqJJMPYU9DOSAqUUUFWQBoTio6ybDeM2QaYN0JT/fI4tx7QCeAXbc4RVhmabjwOYDK0KMci6sC01EjneXnYKrxyQ/OODdfYlJTMFhJHOz3Xvnha@j8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ixcsd)

IE 5.5 is separated from IE6 with `document.nodeType` (see [prop diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/kxh3b)).
I don't use `document.doctype` because it is falsy (`null`).

Answer (score 3):

## 313. [Lolwho.Cares](https://valthe.scheffers.net/testing/lolwhocares), 14428 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
*{+color:fff}:,a,i{color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
+i,: u{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[os]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on;z cop>s'0}e}eq67+?4[0]tfc;text
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKk9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vq9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrdGGrs3Y3dN28saaUlCX7uj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d0LcE8z5lgX7MBp2W2AxMbumeXYb6wRuGUYu2/13w7ejlnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeypCR@dSeuMmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2DOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1zijMokuBscfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@2j3yafX/Osp9qkJSA371vRa9LrOntvWqH09hME@P3nw4Lptmn2mug57cBMlPcN2J2P3YHwdfpbtdi3HZIZW1Izrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD2wR5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILL@xxT4MAJy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@x1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mZNbtwR5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQma7bzUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@4ue5QiUbKeL6Xg@t0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwhOhi1x7bR4QLt0WvTIiytNoLan5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4pyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@cFT5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@4/uR9l1YCM2qgpBSStsEvGWMR3ZOdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttjHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2Z5wBS7dtnKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SriQoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3HCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9KzXE6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKYLBPTQvbDmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDmwiR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOUe6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSfRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurEz1nPHSwmjYuXgyDpPRurgP6FOYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrngPWdp3oOIByMYLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyTVCadJ1QnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjrM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUgWoY91XNnsDjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@sYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyW5OBr0wI/jgXJ3nv6dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qju6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrN4QNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gVdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzjIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92I3rwcX4tdvkl@lnA4KW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSY3kw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@TUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4hbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4GdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Rqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfwuSOJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMe6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9HriFH702a9vR6M6OFltorTzo3R6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPABBczxzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vY/cK7JBpBmdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abK3ID1GTJ3uUWhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAT@QEhRQBotkUtSfaEFKHncjdYZbThzqHmAxroEo7DJQ0aECiBEyNugcdsseN4SWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsK2Hl3u9H0UBSg2eNlBARiTZ2j8dYNmIKpBc9X3FsQFsCTq1U2eW4N4ISR99XEngCskoOcrJPWJHPT@yzSft6RjtoiZ5kLHWgK9mtsVyWoPLnpaGyjqrRBaqC8h9FqiLzYngCfYN5yRYzVBbeRpaHWm9FoBLK4RhiIHh1KYl4UGE3Z@i9WasvVAJugsLOpVET0D8TLfVAECWETuAX2hsllQPB4sDhsKe7Jw8roixyx2TTdkoLFn23ZfbJehO9y37YRwf3jnaPvt5YAqNvN0vXLZJ2ppDDqnYyVbvOJJnRjNJmGMYc8P3GetgYcNGPLAlnprrTkKo0a0HlMvXJeXj02XWSgCaE5KAYwIz3NZWG@wGlS2qaXu9aJcy68ThEGQTx/TL1gPkwAwOiju6mj8/TyZs3mHnXkRoKe8SsPzE5AN8yeeD44TR0vKaA@U7NDq8RKSxoobaD/Z9zU9inj8@nqDVfR4ZU6RDLfHr4YP@oQmB7pndm9fsqeUl6Y9ClzFFbA57vT9qWtMwPiD8wtVhcmyOO@jThupTArdYCged5y1bABwDYxNFcpvYHftK8HuC@dz1tZKu2Ag6gb4JwXa8M60Otj0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhXlkFVktrrMB1sdpqZbNWPlMMV1uteZztMNABKcW26@uNI3A681S00eZapFCrBfrHj24g7pESCU0B1cfM6zON4vL6ErZeVJtFveQetNDcvqU9J4knM1lJJqN@x6fW8qjNGfK/P7XHsZTC37oCfiH23d0D477vWXTUUQcGNRqwCY4106iDAw0tD3jEcftu12VbEIZrh36EoDatTOZu13Vu5JCJlpjUCI5cgPzF/hpzCHWN/YYajhQq3Fzlox6m412AlNZzaSQSUYhAJcm/9so8N4Fc83QfH3xjHyoRPZtKBeYUXUCCUBgiF5paIVuyYCpEpAl8liYwGMW4Udp9BzU0jICJFoIuCLg7d15qSRJTSy71vxSlr7o3KP7KnV1jLbDhrAWGEMkOnjx9dPBk//HuF6djI5td@M6kijkgHMTXBF1I63G6YWnd4kUTk4XgIlA2Rli8QApMoIHid4dPvBEIbg29aByBFVzDx39iX3V7TtRTrifmAl3VV06Ls9BjLHzcqwgIDe12HxsjIz5shvU58k9vPB56pWQSSnlv0tSg0Zp81XL7ZjdJ4aBi6PeTOjZdDg6xX8NbFgKQ8WYWD8H7tEB1mFHHodkfuNB4oaE4FA0sxsFTZ1Xf7vagLYzjddZI0QIOptQk29BCgLZyMkgbCWD6AtqKt59PMmftr@hGgfO1njIySdn3tlD8we9Gx4KmUwxqKyCFcu2Tnd45vcNmIKUR0nUgEaZtiSEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9HqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDraljD4yILe9wkkNV17cXrq1EFBP71DuOFAWG1Wr@l1pcxuBtkS/pUycO9C8pB3fQvgXTICa9KbrZBnbfOmOGubVLraLDkeDEWdow7Z411QpN64IK/bVrjsYYBk2DG5teA3iZ7fJZd0CPUxqIQPpFQSChTUtMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQBs3pvB08GHn0NyBBvdyPe2G/Worx71Guwk9YZAROpjbqGU9rB/cAy1Y8D5KKUhc1FIswsrit3npsc7KSGQGHT0w0NbLYBAnfFBR7QTDLYCE1Aoap6D5AC@wt7S3ryXERv9wGkQIeGEnQ@gQTg0aNAFOQOBeUJ2eUJ4TGSzmKQzx71wEFrTYgW1aY95H787GeFgnt0Opw28pw3uB6BR4kJynUb9mlaL97LywJQKaASabGANXOxKAO2KRIFFSTD5iCG2BT3sqIZilVJx4ATgq@zuHkixlsX7i9QBNqKApfZZdDxK7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVJn43PIBNmX7iE4B6IoMRbOolET2gpJ24A/L0nPpb0PGer@5Kw9m4BykGDpPNiju0nOttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sMrqxsREtRavRBJh2wLSNph00xcG0QyaVTOhPQxOFSJAJXWsUAu3q0auaD3mq1JEHpqg5vLGHMbNWKqXrCbOmi7eBbwWyAigPvlV8AZyoUqmgUVHk6gUO1YD@Hkr7HvLOcWtkDwUJvgoKAf8WNEgTEaB5j9r8yCpj23Q9RQaVETQaLVQxY6PoaS11Wj@9PG3HT6@iCQytlM0KtA9BeI1jA607cidDUNxqmZIKsk2ppUv1crMSTUW3YrGC2oeITEX5pKDETU7rWNQCnoqdnkaBpII6tVZvRPCmCUNRAkIBHh0bWhn9fiyqXRYg/qZSV@JRCKtEEyCWK9Eo0KWFRPAo0dgjwJnogT0FUkLBhCouPKZAApLGpLC4fsMa9majsIeg1w20bOxBnw/GQ2EgKR6Wkm94@LBCt9DS9/Ve7g@UW@y8Q31pOOPSXeKYniYXJob49e652hm4YzP5uQaNJi1UXUY3oklVhZqQXDgkSvZj28MibDqWO/HCPY1LO0AxdrA96U1AWPqzZhLAVfZQslo9l0U37wJ0FgzzYFWCI1YqH/fyAbRbGtwoRFErwcES0C5oOokNchGnmvBeGZ2Q4KLH75vP5oavtSC2MoVhKYzI7jruyFKBJBBCoskfNFVIqjIxo@SAer5ujEsIV6rSsOFtWyARH/Rdk2jLxXVoPGg4CIWH9jkEObLaUh/kRwfEo8bzYmS1k1sSDc66ox7UEJAalMRGkFsD4ZB0vWFbG08hqBTDCjfsyFt3oHResLZhGLlWtlPy3ZArgNg9yCRslTrQxPWdVB0cFZHJ@7xbyG@jPzm8v8/7TqiyxeoV@9EaA7c9Ab1StJuOLKebYPvAT7bjDmwggx/@zVn/yHXHvJUPH6t6Znij2R5M@ib1@VzvllkbruU23T51Ba0LOvc/GXlm3@SdUL7r7uePQdd/dnJc0UohT0nzfLA2buyHXB4tp@dBeMyRhln94SGPM6a8mZWx3vIno6GYEQ45dJiIqWiQR759Hu39IoVjKMK@gPYDnIYGurLoRaDPwFJ4LJJHnJqGM3qE5aWeukL7lW2wwJ9O/rjiOMf2UjfI/nzc6SxYp8n6TEXR1J9bZ8iaT1FbaCOGUcpyTzhfbcFPGFCO/ATT1q77E8IrmGLQs/r@COIRKCY4SgZ1ex/VJ2iboCbO545ZoEgPcTCEJDQOsbEW6JrejW4LKFNDlfuWIhtUTqAOS6LmIm0mmejiLlNJcVwxNOlx6elC0556T7arfMAam04j3mpL8s73zQaA2K6W/dlEq7xhTNFo4I2gEm4QgpJJw/Y3khpMwvCoT12iIGXJS0KrYWqk1NNpfr@e9IgIHSafnk4/SRlfQOMD53xt3kl2rTJGt5Ja9M37oVs9EBssPl0kGeTDxOm4/bbKB70g/xlvLmFGiKkGwawzEvhgY4/8CWc2TmIREwNBXIbmqt2Aey3rqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyyt2eJ87esBjXYueYN@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@ZZlPBBaUIHeqaKAlhSkji5jCLpGYREoDqcjevkULmW0ajNhAxhnDnL5XfpsW5OMjF5B9JGZAh3UOEhpiegqKjlNJ9htvi@O/6MIbBsnzazqvei6Hw3Gd03bOXBpFCkyNlKZnUc8MQg/O@jdDdmyvR48FrwEO3K@xCjtv0OzQY4kHGkwRw/RkQd30QsOG7DSTR/SiHvslMS9OTVmItml1Jk6XxjTRzNTXt/hUiwXy3Gk27VVegQg428x/L/EGshJLnqFlNN0vPdjBA9UiyE/eJpon/fqsJrZAd6ikxhBKvP/LN9tA/5u504P6CvszA0MDNAXMKbWzMrNEUPygx/KM5d3uk75tEmHIdBvIljmCJJn9wLAcNA3tqyroGwMcqBA5DryJD9BF17AZx5yPM/rv5ZEsG6pzQG63Vvm9NsuLR0WDStBcbBMRuM5lWxSIhCzPBGvKB3ZCDXcUuLcj5U/FYsTMPN97k/GEP0EdvjUT7SHe68qm8JnKmk3dggap2bStNVk@Ms8mbVcdnnUDtTi3xO889TSyrIJWIgaZG2hcnnyewJHdheref6/yNq9fkxf0uo0rPGfiDdUmte3b/IsKwmBNDKM@f67yYouVSoFhNdXsPj0@kBMFdGAUMcciiTNY1RDR7Gtk7pvNGapCvY/nsmC@AkicSiseT6VXDFgPh6vDY/uUwheLy0NPtRanx7KehySfJavyvjlKsJg3e0uuQnVlD8y@arRDxpXCfNl0hxteg5FSCmOd4zjR@dKcm1MfK6TWpG@O5qY1LD7Hwx@cWNXPLaoNUZZbbt/2sED3V0lNf87dPC6cp0yP0LwKexkl29AQxXpcDUzLpYDbGuNc1BVs9QEyjc8BxZm2IT7R3FXEarkXeK/UIHrQGObP5ZXam6VYfYB8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@HVC9uz6LGcsGdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8jbM9u@967Jie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8f5QIRcIKV2/RUj5GpDr6OK9UrSfJUdnt2UQrf8a4cTZkHFNLbtMUolBndWpg7YBjgguT9mDVIFCakneh7giYhzLuTBn/vsXqD1WkdavPYYz0qhBwcMAxQIYxiOuZf8isWXWx9b@MKF0A2z@tkSEMvesb0F9Rc8bWcqMlP6RIfRU6sNFVKc/sSbW0rbGYfOVhcuI17QzPhyplEjGphgCwFEHXPMS@HojGocfhDVW1fi1VpiY0Gq3btdmFoXaEBTwIbaen4LhKRpuhug6k@FCri400Jyj9STrDf0i7bYXsEOXj5VDhVuUpQUV3bPoXtto4o08nHlWyaRSKaHDhIZyFj7WNabSQdhXNn8uREw285jnfnH4bhQyLo@DyBKe27hSBBmr2vbkuVhMOrZjjWf4/EBp2nTd/sfkFAjVto3aGCiXNId3XY7dUHfE6hQ2773wsM@j2VnVb8FrG9G8BPpgu3ldpofHmj4oN1UcTR3gSNfi5/oenNDI1W2x4HJu7Bbis3r7q3VJ0SGiawUtv7bUcQ3VbVp9k7@mucw6eEUtvRbeotAQo8A4aszHiudj/JFrQmk4A2LZbWio9KyBRZ9rFH2z/Wri@a@VnqYu3qucp5bVSk73rdYqD0Mb5IKDz4XB6ZCyNHYdaGKNcQIhNlX6OEVV2K6SwP5w4lIiHwzMrsX3qFgnKed9FjhNh7fs5sblvRclPjWnBcHmPcyrWQIK1Zk18/z3UoCPZy3I18ng9h63a4W/hd2gH1DaV82NvVnFOj235/SsHp@QHnytKhzAj2O@p8g61AHrbg/nyA2HC3Pnw/Tsu/3@h9ATRSMXlK7bWYrTPq6qxSVhHwV3ZjbBQbxu7b8zx1x2oGFlqelZE6iXPHfsDi2VvlZ57WNfD3@ukqH@6Pcv2om0tqkPFPHfvyj8W9uWXdMdD4f0agz7E48eFFSlxdC36U0dPueFZlu6o672xh00NWGpiQkxNOi@XMQ07XGrh4vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9Xh/@@UFtV6SMzdT7aK31bSDvaKYhv1TC7sf4OliV6aIDiVdrgWGNvrKsk47We6tD86zl8Q5RNLES9gmHSiNfFV6i5fSl1xN7PAcamiQV9PDykQk0rMJdTMtYqVnR4ou5GBbTNVZyKSnpqJCrVgoUHn1l/9LCBLpQEUun@WMVQuFUEkahCS8fQ24xqYg6CO1Q1y3YL/DXwmyopZWc05t0vZsCk/fYt0FFw8fqbguaJB3qtYY6y3TEaxWZjX4SV0/CuwE618RaO6ySXTuuQv70vmq6Nrwa8IKsm6zsQ@vbQ48/mdpZORonJklBW/z6kCGnzWx5Y1pkTNvq8FEQNN2mIg5cGqcFHURt4Zg@dqKjMOeKFxdcjtsFoa722dyz73eV2rJ0/tHy7A/qTPWLJ1bXxEncj@wxzgJdwhXEssvmLd0K@2sT07O/NoGUrWI23AqCj0SOwnsG4NcSeI/Nrt16uJARAZKCwGIKKX8tsD9a3cyLi57t4RyqwLCmYwpZjjMxcl0D2g1LfF7vug92wZgXIL6@cqnvZd3r7nCGy9BmZFrXs26PqZdVvFc1HVfNLluLxMVkMJx44rUcB5qlFe6FHpyRvXdhA3D1NYhW1jP74@U91aEuV9DCRKU4N67Sxr9h990u@0YhxUBpAyUMlfMljHMPquenODVo5CzhRIr7A0c@saNDHfGEvYa8tdJMtR17vL43ZzzGaUL@GxPDaw5c@pB8hE/t7sdCUE@WU@TR7br@fM3zLfU7cN6xOxm1LDQGG5mEmwUiVmvPn9aMS0Vc3IjlItxKWzt6A9Wh60zG6mjirK0VcmtrhRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/fqaEuYGmgd@mhVrQ@Jt4/dnctHLOwDUmsx1QxFbL0UXfflviPt936YjmIN8SZhc3h2qRuL7vLmvvPJ2NrPEHN5hA@E8G960WjhzeGvcT97HruFAbDUFQDo4svpnAwlyP5QEx2CNcLg/0ad8azTGBXVEJcW3DHFpNyN/@3PQhdREHfN8cmyuqIuobpPZfYLqVV@x@0xq9ok6/kHlVk3YRoYfWlNoWqxmGl0F13GpxlRj74xbKyMKIjTd0XYc/Sdqm4KU/Xi9VoCqgx4ePlWs4w3@hX2Bp@2wxqYfnfKKI1ea7XaxK68hqun3@XDMtybH5tABzZFte8hFunkB2uQxTQfvy1sqQ/FoZMm8agSZ7bno0Tr@8qTEHqU8/YhZQzxy1XBwJE4Y1E3RCOx7cIqaDRQN87kATCD8FiWW2JmLvxdvQ6g@aA3qsbDCEcvPIauJyoyZtEzI2pzczk/cMiT0SQpO6gp0FfHGFhTrHYk@hNaLcXm0ttKMWqWoP6UGSeuVwOc3XUR3bar0xsdfMJXrN@6YX3CHNySdkXNFXHSpG1IucNGkJ/dKStDh7DRSavqWOeyNo8yfH67q3/f1bloyHTAYWDjIvjsKsVF1dr0eJdZePpwfCdWSpYu9AkCXBPoJcP1R3V2qeCB7@h/e@moRKuJHL@HuagOi6fQQfkJ@MHPH6EA586nrjjj09BLxx3cEqcYLJykIQePGSgaatVYmA3HMmfd770A1NvRq0qTmm0v61qtoncT22VMs5V2mHuenNFLl8NVlyFzdDHVttVWywgCMN6iN/YVngTbyXDKCGZSPO99STnLDTXEbMAF1G3AtfMoC@5Y7VoUfv5NB7evDo8EQbevrS@mm3h@sxbuhxCzs2GIVUqEvqlTkKjXfyGWlt2xsn7x3r6t6jAw09rKA3H9FQ4YUjcwuvlf2eYutRM2mubAWhqzVeriA@PHn8KD5f@8lie72RO7CUsPPe8XEC17Z89Xipczj0AygdHXe6MvjBvq4rS9j3mUOjg6uk55KYVkE6saA1Csz4kG/4cqty1XKHVvtkNrQ@h8oTJbj3gdHnVibyiXlud7EUsuJKQlFBZUUtl1FCk7OhsW2Ngveq/DyzhygtW/RK8tfK6SioOaSTo/Ry7WHdiP91LYalxEyEjwukp25y69hWoWR0e2hKmt7fFzFd11fR@djsQL6y7MrMWvSwbHy4755/wFCyJRovamCljoGrVPvWqeR5dQCiO4kP7J4XlmBsrpwGsw5AYJ1bWuAvLGdmOiqNZa1TL0oQGie1rfXyDesDBqSCGT7nuCH00jG@YFY9i7XIqNwS8ckoFGRv797BbQGOBC3X@/r0yTP21PRwd5P1HsMYWx@A8VwzeqVivxVurbdyOLU9AlDGWnjd4fLyXGLH5qjtOrPp7YNwtLgVq3barDiAhV/kyerbU3tZXdXi/VpPl08zui1uvo7DnS3oweFdbwSg99/5Z7qeStGeRvjWU/zzlpzxCziLocmc4UZ5YaeTg0A0tFBv0cBCWdoafWRNcToK7w1e1qhfWr/l1tR9eWV1dbLOrbDGLbMmvhtuaMnSWkpfAzC7xo1ltcD5kdu/6LnanjmyvHV5wpcxHU2c8Ma6XkJsjcBXH/L1YJ7m734ciznxuKIsbrAfXv3G133h9mt8yRb4ffuWbYiVWeAQLFYT68FwlyZQEy1cRSkRCFymF3MqFT1bZDu4zX0JKgGFYkQr2gvHj6vGNi/FMqtSSb/CpWZySWZiGVywtSXfnhHg4sZykCamnulscwwum/4iLUYbjLO3jBRLqMn0bAq@tGR41WxZrF4DlDYvnx483T8@2T15dlxL1a9kRazR5Lg5DsTmr979JN2WIe2CbMCwfLNWWuXZh@ho83NUSD0/XQxSdi1plYWkzRMl72CYzUvHSSZpsWJSvQL8VJnHRq5Q@6AVh@2nmPJHrDUt8TV@fSKpvMlByxQn5FmJpZZFPDQ9D5Il3K8fv0CuLJ1GVx6x2F8TWLLrum0Ro2ex2y8/xge7B4@eHe0zH8E501zY7XGvUszy7VdRqKsW5FPHpnkPFRYVQaKQV5VK9EEUCBPVoqxES0Rp61Pgc/DmUwcXl4rQWyy2SfCBgtEgU5L/5ZvJq6iGU/gU8Bv1kYoyQXn0wE5w2def/aTNtwb3N3vwzxgZDUiC0aJ6SSzpXLGgEylKBXO4@qQR2oqb1m4Ge4DPT2@RaGd44MoL2qfp2h4@Cm2rwY@NEVss@RERg/jbCWNfEG6XBA3ZcxsXbnIcOrh70SIr4/Ax7dilsV08RgV4npm0PT2gPnHGfIcQsZ9ABPhICwRKgm0SsnwzeznkMbq9AazctLq2wzwHFGxrXGKvgM@wv6XEVw@rajV6I4gPmp@fo/bGg37I443tjrzk6Tj5/te@m@yWGZinqXvw9SviqwPmX@XmF0nM65tbIs3jDyOB25gJrHnkAc2R3qETYxy@SntOLNy5yZeUzB5A1pwTpdE7j4E/VRCwczix2ueQUcBikEtidTaPzxrVY7iPWimZRDbCsSuNZqRaUz495Np@arlsLqMnAUn13AdIGyB3cekbB6goJWB86dweVl42gb22t5mM@ppVyZV5biY3nRdp@WWA6Cb4lS56iFyNQRgIMg8BblURDKqTuK5gUJRHUT2KoqjtQj1D7lgf4bcjCCGzGBCL08jCHXWneHTQeDTz9wVs4nE8oc3xNwUgVYdahkyKLIkFxU/cMbDMwlJqvqAYp0fxOg033PL40Vi0HR/yoHazNM3Xwfm78IvypWG556DSqevVYzhv5ecI4hhBlORlLFt7wU7Hp049yXmTAZv@SLBsmJkdMP@TZHcFz/J0797cjC12fSs1JBa7e@y4qJg@gMSwmJE00kk9p8yTlMksTZJIkYgGkoNbRLyF6EA0gZhoWfYrd@jt7u0ffPXw6fGNDcfIZ/S6N5Dk1e34qaolavXAEA0nazFL7j1IHj@@98DPiDnSuZAEBu1FpERfl5J5exNBzucvX0/aMgyvp241xs/5Isfr@KaNdahRoBt46KmPiJfmEKoPaCXA9ciNwjJqZbPrUJrDS4ZA7/FlXDdQjSmXV7X6dvXUiURvcsKSgvAiom1hIQDTqbe1mURmv5k4TFhwhN0JHr7jhctienlZlDfTuO8NLiQdu2fzHX@ERcghlF4/GhCRkpb0va4sfYdc657vS2XwI/b4DjnhfUFCCOdS6ygeAnXin9aHUmS@q57YUK4Hrb6@3ZT8/Vj4xnL@/lfBnnJ8L5WYIom92XnEMXF@37Q01WjCQExBaUewEmzdHnU@PEWCAo362tMJtD6fukO@Vy8NDN23fNORC@L3/oSPMFvsq5MB@OvQ68iiTjqQ3CoEBkpGA1S5/gRSQmxRN43jJoAQXw03qhMJ1wbtbGyqaD1r2ra7INtjSgIk2ie6XmfBNnaYaNq2zonKlGfzXFhbFD/FxXlhsn/UXobTOQJmzdRsp21NY9GLqFKqQ/xoH714fh5V5GW8RHsqik0G29c3VwzQz@vrJYk5FqXT37lwmbQoFm9KCbC7DpjvCuQfFFIsaj1PovOeKqiLH49Hj8AIakSsMzCHLDZx@M5JGqPP2GnMSdBWM2qVb77msHicmkjwIgeNUcgOmXj9HTOdGYslK8AEaOs5bXy9sYespmtaHcwUicI28QCfPdC4cBcSRYJWLQQpEdgKshA0HAAjXkg0zuAQBt0l3BxmRPtPLXGm80yoL8NFmlCqWfUOC53DtKg5ysViSWToolQsMuC@m@JQSwLYG3LO1@WBumKXA6AZNGg1KTIX5DclXoTijXBEHortEQCdSGjDRH/XBAaw5tsZtnojvGP7DpQV3Oil9OzkQaOgJGUWbLPQHdlt7Gvje/4GjTZxSgMU0@SC12iZt9E@xWC4f1aD7@OA2zs9oAIjXxOpkTAZrp9KOudNXV/L9SKgyAXwmcEKQKxFafjgcKM4f9RzidtyYf/zn@O5p3JscyeXbvTP49FsqgwPvZxlWfbJ5qmqbtaMbKpyd7NumuNTmZnJzNb9c6vXaR50k6eyzNIsk0xuGbnXZ0M9t/Wipr2e1uVaoZI4qz89Y0@ffvGu8U6Rp@cz@TTG8hG2d/hW1iEBkVKeFRneSy86kHDptaaVLkcB7ukpnmcq5@Vkshatw5@cXsLFPdWqWlXbqb97p9TykKbp7DSCxwSyw7vkTO0k6mkyDOXYtu0kOx167Tbcbo/V@UG3EX7F4zGVCQu1xu3YYNohu@mu1e1O9s0Zt7cjE3w9GIuwj7/x/PlzNDyni705EuE5dObHUWqY2QgzUsaf/XTjKnH5tLH9Z98aJK0NfB3i67tXj9F8rGc/2dj45N69TCYBVOLmp994@vXd3d3M/UT2aS27k1FTG9t/@icbG4axbSQ36p6n16O1s7MvZCOVkbU/@3G08fTp1zwPswWvNNPBiM8C3DrqVGfsDVxnHYZ/Mr9ph8wmmpudN8yIvIkAW0dm9GtEGC@FFdKSwtcG06s7@f/6/cPXkXGkaiSfj@A9jryO5AoRbgQDfKX9r/NINbKN3nJXkVmyUqmAMf9f/x2Er34V4KDLbBse1awPKzeLVNUKBXkbqebAoBsGxPt/ffObt3T73GU1uORM3pB36nBt0bUt4eZWaiqZvOZdL9zR7zDmjHtjy8WXzV8OvJhZdqDVfVSLx@N1TYVLa1CgpK4bp9RhE2Yt6m@JBNZlxm1YyG7OJ8IG3J5HiKeAqYivuFlYEKtxi@fX/T1fcpWf/0NfR1Ikt3HXul@tgihMV9Nb1ThdG6elEid/kuULsuvelbcgy1L0eMTgBQKzKjOWKhhyIpG42wCt0kCaqlNBv0j0VI5GIi/nJPUpG2HzLxa2ighSsqAM/gL@9vH68//tz3/w59@n3w/o/o@4D5jTtjvJLYZHXrPzKr9YtSpXR/LlKX3cZalSoVRINtjVaWyrVq0fMT316dtoNh09xkpCJ1@nit/DGQmuahUfPhr4VY1wmyo3ze2ESzX4IB/zIMv9MSGZGBORQBUspkuptXOQsVU/RdMbF6vdhUySjXxRrleNrHFYlVO6TNlWZL1Nj7kRkaIduDbgR3@4drDzWNjgc4MsuQt5XXJtBKjcfi2UXilSqyXrVh0UWVb1gdzdKG0USrmSAZmyGnB5FejIeViaaHmtoBkgPt7VNtgR5/U6i/vXafzW65mmNYSRDC7equpOI1LkH@CqSixyCVf93VbtHbCuiLomyml8W61X4wIjeGmNu/W4enVV017Ey2Xx364GxjJd3AQJqV@p6vYLgFW7CZUDpafWeLENYOPbte2Ku0e31kASq9GMG825d@svqrXtRRACyt27cRS1dwFOdROYVInHN1V1o7YyDQC4HgMlYBsy8Gr7qnpV27662t6G/zY9r8QbbK@2b/zpNb9W@Jm7U7E5rSWrp8lTwTZ1@NaSVbTRkqdgqMIb/EE1JEVAMZlKkS22FRkyPZ8GE7NK@paRTmann@T2QTWq1VVswVTUmp7L1lUuqV5qrKTyzcP1Qk7RUBQ13E4D1/tp7KUUefn@y/8F79P3X/4@1vtQLItSJLmFzYMibyXA47HDHj9@jPdjx4E/3I/55aANWjxGO4c/HO7D9xNYcxssDiAUmGwUcnIjrs8MFtmWc3kUC79044pGo//opVHMR3kLGtfFvfTA8peWXf/ol1ZdUuRtEct5y2M8TVKEyj3kBZSfKhov8dF8jb9Hb/D3eoy/kxb@jl7jj528wd/RGH/scRN/Tz38nbzG324TfycD/N17jb/HY/w96@JPilRA297cSfVTrZR@pp@BwWapEUv1Uj29jU2BlMVSs9SMpQau3gaTBb8UmOxUh6W6LOWkHF0HRzCMWWqMpg68uvDrAJQR/GwcGj/TUy0GsfSx6qDzf@j9FiSZcirVoA0pv7RAL9Z0LaXl7Dpum16T60axwDQksdaovTyN1nE/TqOYYc2ZtXH6kkU80KnLkeTpaZL3DjAjU8Yd1q@uGo39J/cbjSTKotPH7uH8f3g4CH@u/Q8O3ceH7sCF/@Hh4WNmVeN34@pduCrV@LZ47USq5Z3TkooF15cVkeT2zmk1raI5F4dyb6Bd/COvOUR4VzdOpSgDVeWiTApR@eK8fFEmQ/AJhkY58CC8cQNYloUiBTZlX6O6gOv8gizxgcaL56eBiRuSzy9OsWEALb7gDxpn@PO/wd/@f9f/8TMWq9VBwYldXm3H6FLwpyiXV5dX4llVYjHxEduGH1rANwa5vKqikTxdgqkWU@rK1RW3g2dM2eYAqxjHdpUCzz1C6Y8EcVK8/BH7b/vGuMV1ijt3m/Oh@tPTaSqllJv@TsE4TGW@pRFTpUznvmw2a3r9T39M@0HvKOQpmymX9S3GP4yMUS5n/K98oVwu@B@bsVjx5lVN7eg50HAyGUUpl@Fjxwebgs8AbAHA@h9ZgGp5ZovKfTlyeXBIOyWDmMhGFEwRFwyxFG2ojmdzROWSfOdOTJz5ubOr3LljFFNv3wY2wyFY6QtWjUbbHjUaaJ9@@1ZuyDR0XszCd6rw9i3IsqjijmJP8EgXiCim6uwTo0pxFt0RECIPzkxPGnMseqZnjsej2Bt7mJBxko8nK3TiQirljk6jP/vet751Gq1UZFUm24yOADAWlt3ezmWq1VwGzLkCUErevOSHj3TjRV252kzKnBpM3oxGhJNeyCtcNkbRHao4tlOFAu7hxS6vIpTtLJNVYiBdFdC0riL449Z6scjtWSYXK8SL4lfZUFgVlAD@wwZqOp7Zym/drTP6TZddKJLLl1ZFv6pcWiXs57sqt8R5ergq0LpzJ10EmhZS5VOp0bi/e7LbaFRkWcb6EB5oScJdwmN8hqNojTI8W6zXMH3102i0VL5LzKEXsiwSLQt/ahRqCVYoEhkku4NLfiHtki5a/xuSQW98SKIzaAMs8ch7Nr@fPtrd2z9JGNug0xgPdvcSxvGzexEdP7Pzb3JO4/fR/u79w2cQ4Omj/d3j/U8PPt9/9hTsPXYxv3wJLJ7zd9i05PuCPZdejd6YlmVaE8tqXEwmF6/ZK9tu2EDY/sS2bbc7Yp7VsCxrCN78qwx3y/bMV6/M0ZAu9v5H33n/o//u/e987/3vfOf97/zgZ1/@4Dtw/wTu7/H39/5tMYvPn335z373/W//Dlj@R7j/CO6f/uzL3/wmv@n7j@H@zyG7PxZ3yB@/JYD1Kz/78vs//tmXv/pDuP@luH948/61ny6/f/Dt1TeG@/7vrvfzvX8H9@9xWL7f7/02t8P3Df@/zf396g/f/8a/5/8/FT80/s773/hjfIiPf/rDP/3P77/1Hwyj8Kf/5v23v//@2996/@3vvv/2Pzbe/@a/0VPhx@@@/8Ef/NUf/t5f/eH/RP@f0PP3PuT//of/9C/@17/43//iD8X9U7j/PZh@@hf/ARj2b//gR/j//h/87R/9CP//87/62z/49b/9lX9Nht/ihv/7X/5b/vzrX/tPf/MvvvtXP/3m3/z6T//mt/7gr/6PX/0/f/M//fV///t//T9@Cy1/66d/9Ue/8pff@s5ffvuf/@W3vlzx/M7a55cfYP/lP4DNh@P5IXA@JF0fa/PlL4TP34ca81iAT4C7/8n73/xlYPDfYOz9d36Cc1vhXvH/iaGTn5/wr/8PGIybaUaXFJjg/vX33/kekuh/ABLBP6DXd4OPBRf@8d35B5D1X1wLFLFKi5VnwSjEt6CFsVUsigo0cN6mkD/78p//OIjilxehLrhBjN9FSbXg9l2Uce9/9M33P/7H73/0W@9/9CtYm6mZYmI3oerre5@hClSzH@APPeY@xB94/OILiH8ap75SNY5f7Avh@MUXX0jTt0mcTH33Ldh@QVb8YtwJ3Jhw8t2EPU5VDfvhxpRv3ETrt@GokQxxjDZOqsCWr6dk02waFxhNsSsO32APnqZbZJzik2zReSrhY/6fG6cSi6Mf0QkZnxvJIMKJKLhRykI08enUpxcpTowrK1vchoaRKN5MkWEKptP4FFqkYIAY4uB0L84qlUocA1Y4PvDJUasWGKESj1cg3Riah0k0Cghieo@gQMhK/Ig1tipTHjCO8Ko@OeISWh3JuiHHC5X7EGFlep8hLAROYF@@rFQLlWkVwb3j9IhP4/cIJwRWiU@r7@C7QjDj2Kt0/x2gUqjE49UCRoiJ5NmTaPBMylLiKO1xFhd5AG/qor3L2CeyXpD5kMYGEoz7xmd87nuHBtl2wP00viWSQ3/fSPcWEXyDohKxMO6@Q6riDtce0QPAVVVN0xjcOHC3w@6C85SDilO08IpzCHHiCOKAwALYEPMiTvkbpw@IP1LZ@ugrXpV4ajY3N6VIVU7LhzTEE4dW@@isxA8QecubRiUm54oyWls09Zunztp8St0OW/e34KnDf3@DZmTHWZnQ2oxi716U8fjYJ3F@3727xT6B1NN7bicxNZ52M9i7jgndjsdlA2KtunHpBUg3CdiXAL2VtGmFBpbiUiLBmFaJoBs7PDwUqJHFi4oUB@430jp@40jAZDKJQAhNS2iJhHhr9CYLTRg0chVvbRNpTr2RzDAyZWjflBlasXBzRId2K1q@e/cOMotmZZQOoEXJxAQNI1MgR7Dga0z7/Zm/cMDIFCXenGZ6jh/xHaMTABWmSCzGthSJz9/lSPhXLGoUClE0KZAnWmzLn6@T0yW/k5D6CIMQvI1XyCq@494h2zt8/Hj/ycmwXmeSRUczWo3hyG1ZnrdOMMcw3O6T@3x6v1HMIRqRWg1jPikZKJak/VKKhObB/aOD4xLjNBE5FAsgKWXqABakKOpSZDh8vh0RcxpkPCvElY/xWZqnP2YU0xhhtSxFWhY2S4Dh8M/K0mOve8@dQls@IcsJPYdNNIW6UJn0dbdUqrzTM3kJ3vQ9YbirFV8CC6UTJ4Fr29tENKl6qVK3Nxohg3NStSomBzFdqh7vn0CAk0OmGymNQUv/MpM3MtlM1kjnctm8oWdyxUwuW0hDXZNLZQ1DL2YyxUIxfyVVv2BTDXFVwdyv9C2nO@5t4pQc@TQlh@ixWUsl8Gek0/AEiAk9m69vbPQvVUTwlNjiEudWXcHnpYoU@ApcTPqKxL4CVnBBHDhhionZageHZTFlCDebiPF5Q7KehcKtSKfASBycNAxf5SEUH2jsh24psvGNb4xZtQqNbPXggRQBKdVj/rQZ1W5rPY34qD0ZWeTaZaxtf27jCTJa2/aGfXMGZTOlSZGrq6sOQDp4wIyqQZ88RBufVy2yaYL5ampK///1C14RVa1K28Mq8ON2cghGE4yZ7aQJxiYYs9vJJhhtMBa3kzYYJ9W0ntpOTqCakLb5Tk0MF4JW5LE1xY3huJ1c9ax@R8MFAhWZIjDkbbHzYVWEq@JKC9dsV3C1IM6QjymXUrvSdlt0apXU1ppue6Z541kfZ9L33VElCtpY1Hew8SBQXMVVqbG6NnSHUGca2Xy8pqdAROOtFxJGIpto4zz8oTnGdRY72VTpwnba7oX2xeNHD8fj4ZFFM/R3MsVSW8M9GHC19E6hlM3WazVZjtcIdh1PvuOFUt3YAEa2zLYK747rjD3VKNQhcNseVSrR6E5a10vpVEG6ClIsAa0wGVUJw8UR/QTS61LwfMlxHShfW5dxSmep0@lclRJmwr6cf0vmpcq/gAhXcTPRvAw@y2rIX9xOlNhk7ngllcwOVC@XLT4RryQb2YJcrpXn3/mcXK5fSXcHVts2cVb@aeryRqBcSr4K/Jym0NsSTzn0BAnnyQWO4vtXVWn6WA3kXX0fqrFafdvf2Qo5yTBUI62mdVVP4/8Wg4H/D/dvwN/AJ4RKG9IJru58AmIP5LrDHuFG2mOXnbgunZl2z2qt8LHXM2me3N7I9by/h597pnPGne7bfEulwOmhiYcleAN73Fvh49lwgIsQrdE/GIT9QRMQpAJIHu7BY9R33WUe8uzZ0xWpfBxsYgjE4LsYgvejg08fnoTeJ/u7ew@lHLt3@OT@tVdWeMqyR/sPToLPPHf1g2YDEF/ff/To@qd4RVADwJ7cDZbN@wZdwom2d6D9c0cYs7m5MYXG53wNmO0FEz/5Yr@SdOIvDDMZlvCmxVp8XSg2yGgfDaGX6fmiJA2Z416wfIq13X7fxPMiOxtg2TNxwYuFmkafjjXFqC/cUb99YbetDekxrq0p6ngoHiIhPQQgg0mLFq3bYwl3ZWrjSY44ctDEw@gneFrqCkt4oRUaR3a3B0L7wvU9SE3TZHB/7AXhrfA1Xm8x5nGQ3Q2X/k3vUkRChdIcm5FC@c4d/ekIOLtaSJVKXQuaHEPXq@5PgbvYhD0DfjdHKFY3k2wzK@da8gOmNSLmFihxXbvmevXhEStgf3bLTGe2QKfWUS8BRdK08hFQoViiwFCdQlW3ZoA6dZpKmhnXKb8BlX5Y9aKpK@vKep3Lx3cyUBWMO60yCnCJlUt//S9@gty9lQRBFtFlGScDb@iSRrqrUSxkC8W0UUgUioVMVs9lswndSEDTIF@E6FJ6Qc8VskU9UcgU0xlQBsE1W8xLET7TKrlFIOFdArBOC0942yb1V@tVpQgfZGJvYqbCImbwPWGyBWFkPNPbG9Nqwy27IhsZpqcYtHwAoslaLPLgwV7qwQNZvocfOLS@l5LlNn5kC6lU/p4sW@SyV8D6W3Z5mAJulCGP@UcqdW9PliccAO4xKcs9/NjPYceJLNv4sbf74AHG08EPA8ODtzPuwj/6/kcevDn4kU5Tz4ssvw7Agb9dHlGGMN3HD4wTXR5wlz1wk@VPfXxSKYBwxP1xCA/9tO7uyvIB/9jdRZc9SniWo/oZfuzSJcvANVhyZLkLhu4IyqwsN8GI5UeWW2BqzUyww/P0cCNCZ2zK8owTCEkky1PybbbOZLnh22M0Dx8@NHvjttXl12zE3y1ADVzs6WT/QfPTT5vdbnM0293/9Ahd9vYemp3ZZNTsNkWwZgMuF8KAy9lgdv0CHA8aDbO/1OUzcHGuuTRmDQtxa5ivASdxdTGSQWMPXPbAZdn4HIcG1wC8NvG6N4D3PbNJLv5FLvSeNptyGRkVVUg6FBfKDJ1PmxiYrZFbxu9pZYOxaCyamNVyqXqZHNgAlMVU@YpOw43h08SWunI5q00rqXplWskbfGJHJyafTo2sLSc2Bjt6MVvaMHd0IxOflnDNsduJsqiq77CYfmfrDYs9UXaMdKYkn@7sqHJNr@8YeqGUy7/YmsiyUsLnTjpfAo@pKLRj8aHU8vWdfDYUJJ@Pm0mjlM8r5Ssgxxjq1yaKlUYsdmGZZ4qC6GJ7C5LAz@KdUTrtcic2TUwrHC82U8rTil7me2Sx1A1YbdyQcdIauyMOsQvgpjupEp32K@vFggzxJ5MxRQHJREIE3vN5W8@/dnJ2cvIFyCxoyYp24FN@hGRZfH76cE@DpqH4wo0UtQeoqrsjbQ8Fy4IL3@fPtzoB2ag9hEoStHnfDteBjNy@tj@F1jnq@76Dvz2WJjY10k4eLsA5hkYwjxmX0ZZpFwanZTHcZ9JuM7NSBZPZZjHCipnKBVXPjWq10qgM@IG91SDUZ4w2YZyDOfA47sHiXgp@iWsjhEOjkroqNyvTyBTgNCpM1V8O3PZLI94qt3F7yXuVexi43IB3s2xVLDy2WI7I5c6OU2Fs4nhmx3pqjXCp@sHhJtRBuGAi1mGWsslO6ZDjPdSmr9TqiDlzzJ5MBjFTrTaVRavQJ5Im9jU/yZe0ggdHvK/KnQqLvVDKr@FztMlibe2espMpt2P3WEMBm9TLzssOM1guU6Zz32IICQoR0YYOD1Yq1c9Av@GAz0olQETk8RnAxJgArN0mB1MZ2lflVqXPYiqbMoXIkyl3KzUM/RYf26os11W19rYuVVX1uVSFclqeRcyKN2nSnsQs1dSNVK48BTs9nyn3IGPNF9PyqDKcjKxyHz5FpwhfqGSWgZxANQDz5m3s/S9/U9lWsxVuVyZQb/ugUjS0RmVadnCXE2CJSroCDvFaJpXIFqC@z@YTUCEboADkEulEJqHm0RZqY2g2gqUOikCsH5MZkxOpaUrTE7qlJ6D0v7TbL5mSOIuBNkIkg4@xu49nJoMNZBJyJX3C22RK3NjqM8gFl5nbKrEpSIoyJgxo3mNDO9FDUEeW2acQiqKy9FasvxlDP5snk@F@rV4q7U@HXwOnmPp6JxfPp@JvFKUc21AqnvVaqpalKkoVSvVwA3hW9BcxbzKoQR6PN/W8UarVmpjCfCqRTqUheXbjbXdbrsr1RGojp0MOXTHSYxgXGFyXmWsjc7sG6tR4ADnTi0ZZ0mhqBMWox4ziqhUuioST8gRAaSiEHVKYxU5lf6leLBrNG9GoEi1jz/KGLDoEQcLxs8xB1Ebv6Dsy6E9ySS4a6GEuKGk1ViqsQl1J2NBmmaIUuZSuLq@2odGZpDlyoCSyDTKpWvWuFCkxBnrcqdjvI7nB2MdOvYtvV1/w9ynOzgW4Eu1SVmN1mhBj2dhSYp/jytMdFgXEzNGgZhjpes3IQ/0GMtP3ahh6GfvNIzj/V6sC5b1LwG87XsVFG5@x2cyMqz5l7zDWjW9KlOjIdbLvVna7R7tl/2sPu@5OJVmWy1E5chmNRK/gJ0Xu0koRg68UYZHQWhE@u7RlAX3eRUhisL1Lv@OmhGdlxMwSlw@1uvLuid2/LKRV3uoHgXV1FdlMUo6ICfflz14aWcgjx/Vn4EPrBzVqqLqyWex3jCRfDr1vGIX044ND5/7ogcX4BPxCpiFXIyylqzifvVwStlk@AVcuFgzZOEtE2N1IOcLO1Kheokn6bHhcfJF/UXjx@Nnhs8MHUuR04@2Gi33SzCcLe@d89WvgMZrORBk7rUSmlUxZzIGqVlV928CddPIMD6Tv6Dk19bbK2bdKDjkDXN7/8g8z0@0CfBugvZYgC7Nxo1rVtwymRIbvv/x93ELhcv/z3Ucs6pkz9nd/8mMj/3d/8q9oZlH0quxRB2g@Aj7RqOfykcvL4eXlFVzcLRupRzhSmbwCZt7Zrkfm6wBKSdPcysczxl2nnBR@9byuRDw1IoYU8tmI91Y4GakCOPl9/mQl5zALIvtHdtbQ724jU@jB8iE2H1q2vCJwReHxy7eMwUer2u52bYNMySQrvVPZ9jt1m73DPvN36gZ7WaniOK@Oi478XuKtarWKUFi0Gk9uRZmRBbfaVbkeZ9TPDE3BF9aWs3W6yNGnG6xYdMDe8rbEqMTplgftvS2HftaW58Gn/2VtvfKYjOMmyWS7TXvLbFssW4X830oCOqfK@1/@TcPI/d2f/NrbxtvGFwa03IrFnG5Efq7//OfgYc1qd7/ZRX3ouCwdDUFzja04PFlrQUsRT9TuMO7fb7xhcw11BrvrQGsdv6Rz1HMoaxp8C6V2jLxt4WLYBGnNtMGJUpakQLskrXjUbSUIBtvCje2hbEqX0lfQCSpTVgFxKX1lDgosBlB9uq2G15@MhjS5Pkbh9HqC3YEgEMNXcHeqDVrEK2SuCmIquXUzKEfZI6qRTsQGlufhXldQi0hfgSBiEzI8r9fE9ebo03ZAyGvohfAkh3YN4q5D3H0eoEG2MUo995BgHDseyAHNWfoKKANEBRt0BGZvg4cyCJavAAEgDTEB2K6zbZZW2KUdj5fnG2ld4Txl3PTL9Ne6ShgMobVxbbUfuIz@wAo0djz2BvlC5DCoZyFLHwiHwcdRK6DzY3D6QqWLFqN/MCiARRu/xChp7M6dOVaVit1WGKUI4Z/ZQ@yTonxwluMKwPz20iftkpxguEVZ2bcN2A4oHid0getUvjdZORSUyfh5JUnw/2CmRY68llXkUMYEiPzipaIFJIPASHaehy22XWG6kVdYgHwLcG8RUrQtVtAIPJ1@ohlf@I5XgOHPI/6m0iB9TsL9fIJvry92ZlDtTXBHX9zyhgsDsUiZb2qDUuxg7IcOQkFS7D757tgjaKDQOK6/Q1YsrSsYbL6jGOFBM4@NDMMpwFkFXxQKfTN4m7gXlIhng/azaLmQod7QdWjzKNroAmdXA0eAjBJ78HC0J84F7gAv8oYChzHyaP8d5HzEmDbDoqPzKCwOjDZH0Ir1aZNgVldjrUGbGUUWI0ajvYKcAJxCgQjhJmi7SONm3xoASseWxXD/JK@UTHZBK5o0acOkxzbwVe@BDVWJ4yXFKYXJC/vMTp7gDraq2wEVWiw/j6AihcWPj8GKzYn6rnvG@vaZxbtvYwuL9z0G@j4orQmg7PwGwpawp9hIJ1gKnBPcF9x5eOW5sZAIhd2IzZSb77S@EWtgjr6lOske4QmE56YToi9dbyXRxPVmnr/9B21iAd9aIHItsfC/EsU1x8GOFpLYyKRCe2ho2IU/jEGD098ABI2gi1vnDBurEtYxIDRb/lJ6LMWQ2q9QBUBlD0oW7gU2HpVwAwjAZNSOtaDoCQHvsE9Y2pDQI9@dReykAjAw6yuL0MENgmI6vHEbMkbjy7ZArkDpHLTBDZceC/bD8D53o5n2aZuzN9sQ4LDSobgqjBcL/yMb@sDSgfxMSd8AxxxguASTjZgcB7BxWZE56CD89eCc2yWSJSV2E1KCIQRBaoBCqoJ/RCkLbdUugcM90@N7R4pdwy4uLjTavm4ysjXLw@3LPTx3NTns2qATu8mxNRiKg6JsPCBQwJ2bVH5qAZ7GuzOlc3CLd2b8LUkdryJmTMSiHS@KleM57s7dHdC2N7jfjEcM9cCmnf1bMTHJg/OfUU9c@vxXQv5TC9ErBMIYgpkmZolWAoAlmq2zROeiXRYO51QgATjkouVb4paRI/9j4Pkme9gJfLhjWsvgfzf7ZzSECZBk3nU6j5qn0Pc58z/F99CeQiDHumC7o5E5i5G7gr6RgWMzUnvYDKp9cgEjVDPsku9faE9rs/pC8GkQHCo1v8nDRrinjXS5HijfzBLdp9x9Cu5T7j6dR@pHW5vWuUqGVleYHOR63ArN94lgZr6fK77x49yFIINizXQOAn3OFuyu4G5VKLRPb/4F@VjxGQN4YggEt2LJ2ovT2mnd8ayLrXo82QVml4kQkOMAulYnml60AzNSv3/eH7regpWDO@BBrSTwRqtWT3AD5xVMY5BBxBicXjZuWtYdiJF3rhCIBAME1MPAEVWD3XHMVsrB5qnkCIxTk@c05ojVBDJ10r6Ek7ADdYmTnhM2DKgeAoT2QZIATXBhfsnhh1X40uH5CM/k9v2qtL/@ADfPidajQMlrRYXLmjJlUggrVfXRBLKjulq5nhTfHbKids0plMwrkf9h9Dc@Gv0OlIvl2BPD8gqjLIWLCk4hAxVCFBeiKqtWQvkKGCS3zL41gpprn@unoraGaLaSfjODx4NJ8C7wBM5YKPNbCs8fWl0mO3IpYIVZpQJJnFV4seTlwicpJ3gQzBPBZj4jiPBcgACM1NJglgg2DQebVipccLDpimAXISSnhOSUB@G@pyuQrItg0HoKjm7G7KmDdooT1mSAp/NqFNSgoczwGE4cqX6FG3vhKKWIcy5ziAsED6GKjXzWqi@NvRZCOiS0rgFARrwBoM3PvSpJ1wWergZfgYzipPRlFP8SbMBlBTAYieAy3/wyFjAZtYFB4ZfjVA9A2ZXjNUnWqV8Xfyl@ywnf0r/1m5apRZ/6omUqce33D2JZR8qGCmhI@9BTGRTI2JJ5Jg4sX9A5InhEZM8Fra554bLYEmUb7JP@WefJZt9tJgcmzg7B03CCE9AVv/2AYyLs7tAdm2M3kynxRpNNbLcsft5msLuOi5tohza9BV2v7VqeEx1DprbcrmN7VgLPXOcqu0VzFfge21JYTxZG15Mk0QfJm7EImvMVqrqNBp7P12jEcA6aUgrmutKUNGTPaFTC9i@YQuFBPAmgh8OY23xltcbK7TBxf2YR7MRuncUOh8IxCpHsMpBhLdD/wbUHGgzz3HnLkXaKRVW6OY7R7vo9d@B2QeubeJqEoa@BP5jDRoTM4ZBwSTATm7Sl0C7dVEpirYSpiKCffXRQ9pkRM5UgvLEIYIEYCTa6TmOk7GhJdI2V0fFgfnzHH4/vcRjf4/X4Uiv8Os68aV7hjh8XdTo2hwAe52ikb0cDkw5yq30DnQVUAmvUq3iAD0axTbOv2ojpLnjdFd61DvBHIvjy4CtA/PNV9F@fgX7w/Q/NPhMPLT2egbwZ4KTAGO2x7/mDmzHwfqAoUmRJdAFr3//AuMAvHjnzAFUIUGNJcDm4ySUUzCE0u71g63Uf8C08j5OobvA9zayqcMclOI3OE@zMWJ1F9xttq2/OrHZM@EyE4PopPoIGG8mrD0s4CjoSei5v68Wg7lICV6jGkejcU2kFy5iJc0VZzVbcix1wD/WUE4YHq@mH7jdEM3bxVXhvNbQDolHccM05t7H7czgbzvg@yn1@XIWQo7z@4TmJa@hvJwjQQWwjk5hHq6wTn0exIEkfUCMEfrXFJOM2pz5E3EH0Zh5@HIluTylkbihQxc9lafFMgOU5bq/L8RBX@DzJx40@jCVvY7oP5rkQq3FgcxG293FVyA3IOB@j1YqFIXKbtTnmOjdkAtpRP52zolZpLBGoQUiSdGObmtukXygStowP4I0dTp/DGwF2rXGDM5SfNuzTEmeWMHIZmMOQ1iJsQEkHKCEqcpILNEK@JN8M3i@vgjhbK@Ns3YiztRBnUAIWowx5kloLUYpcwOxZlwV9qzNeIZ3RCdvO8FontuFyXHOEvRWXUTtashMseh4tgUCOWtHSfgyEcrQdLd0ngxctHZPhLFr6DAzzshV9Gy35xQI9jOCTDHfRXohw/G5FS3sx5Uoam2eW58erRUtBnoKfHf5JFAFSYLpBa8QhNscVyRyPLKjYSKlMMOQYL4HNJ@qHSdCdgj8/5YNOC0BH7OPcIs8szvSFSiNUY/B4oNrwd6NeUpJLojbfP3xA85kCLxhNHNp44TAEHtTwSHRRGHHE0JVGNOANCKLcLC3HiIVqsg9ER8QOHEqZvBg/UU8jfaAdI/caeK7PI6GjXUR4P78WQfAM/DA8MfAqPG@g40dHGOGYrLIELSTqy@iaRGFeL@Iicj@cQ9TXvegJT/31vfBcIrAhmQ46HA3OYWRDd7jIJOSK8@LtcBjqlOOFErn3WjCSCqJkrnAma5EyFAzhwq@sS04oHKK2IILQsZaq81IW1Aski9FpLutCmiovfIBCSOZACbdaZ3Rszn1hJH9c3CSorlhVDflheZQkuRbFJATWcDOgiTnmsQeN133cIujjmq9@yCn2tcQQQChkEAuXr@5H6O8u1999hdonwrUIlinWy6vSm@r12lr2Gub9ebQ3MxAdE@y@slQ5CmKYkxxaByHNfB2v3VDxccoHV/J5pAH0a9q@T7agTXAL3a63LTgs1BJG54uWZwZYnhmrCXVTI@mfa77SomFMAg5PeIDpPGnrceUJX5bF6EL922b/ozN4tJjB4cxDeJSA0TWS81I@mjg0y2VetkFscxsUqXqJcUFOw6VBNs8tQdzT0G0wbAsWh42j@4dPHn0dKt18Pq@IOno2xw9LLfa1BvU4h0yTo4P6YEmzxUjgSRg42I3d8XTC9sapI9@QJVxYgzJgQiw@@4kyrghZFpLn18ouhON@QxQVsM7mxcBckEqo6phYZduCrmMgiDWObZkCiK/eAr0T1FpT6MyHRgNPVW40qPpqNHDyUqMhajHMGn9EXPl5ZCM58UZ0qiM/sORCkmgVP7t/yJ4/3D1hJw/32YNne5@xrx8@Y893n5zgauynz@49OthjcO8/Od5n0sL0SDzcCRuUQNf7VsvCM/hwJ7UMI8h77nDG5U5sT@H2x@aAPXRbFg5TbXvm4G6Pf2iONa7yUPvQHJ1hH6ZNB3gN7DHOt6DTp6AZi8pNm9bd4Vx@Bn6b0KYdYJt34Lbtjg1@JWz7Dm3L85d/sb4NOQjy1l8fm@BKEh40RVOH6Eg4nIF1AcFN8I9jNwDG5POv6OBq2@MBrLbGBOGC66MpeLJ/9PiY4Xr/vcMn9w9ODg6fHLMHh0fw@fTrB08@BXoeHJ8cHdx7hk7k8fHh/YMHB3u7ZMERSGkMV9y/mnjjtSho6J2o0jrDkW86nzz4Wuz1Rg2eXZi0AtFj0YmD0sc2@/Ybqx0tSxMP1Rdc9UhDBSy2uXv06edQ5zPrNY5w@kPBNP9AfubRgWebKbZNsUFhqUJ5K4viCtWeqis0HjGYMTz/wCrT4voYmRPMB06TeNq2xeQ9nKOCfd98DT6VZR80RLQBsBGUP2Glwujckmg0sU0gqxBbq@/iLoo8Nj6JUHxg0Lv@VJOyRBQTc2UQKK5XOHCwP0gvBxbA92BhiGjHI@6BpQML7oFluAWqogc4d4RlhY/J@HCC4pnluMWrwfABDQuzfGBxz6RWbEHgxPONstRkwblPuCNBn06n4b08dGqe6bVsm4J45B9Pbun3ecGw@JlhIBP5UCLNbQOfMgibDg41iGlv/HBNdAVuwHlCZmfssVhF0dgJTg6yHJufC9Ttmw6fAjWfukO8xwq450xFTLO1g/N0aAXI0CUGxLO8FvEIwt0XWqH1oeEg5L0bMZpijiSdaedPQbsNgXs3EPhFwAAgdaGl06KaihaaIhi3I1g55rnAkdhv@y7sH9i5PWlZCwHErK3YK/vNG0UQObHQTvLnKRJ2kEVvrBGolTSU2XFHUMZJrNIJJCgFWz13OLZ5HsYWU0AjTlTNgW@s2CC2l5XqQmxIh@sxOq4TirQJXLwi1iYw5YfEShzPx84D8TU/jhI4HyphPu8O0TGbeD73fOwsgYNIFxZ2v4AiTGPl2Pk5GxMmXP@U5rLjHcMT7QqV6v17p@q7lwk81o6LBX6SpD/pEG9gTIwLigeN89GExRHqXaKk@ccReZMmhhZz8IS0xFLuA4N2YM@Gdt3dRjlw49ONb9rjGpnr9mT59m2Fh1JRMonDRb1ebC7dEqzmR5mgMHUmpoCEZCcgC7I@5tskCGYgr@/iuhjMhTJQxEE5gu32a4f9CBHip6456YBkEWcuiuwO4CusSjMq5kfQ4sqWcH4kX8TuVeJVJTmfUMJC5Iz5IjrhQ9YVJTQtheqrG@DurwcH8vvDwRXWYserh4@Cdn8ttI/CTY2vhsWrpRCsDwf7bg1YXrn9QmAh7YnVgHkleRNawOkBcyY2I8Fs2vUxvryRd1T2AAzWvdiDEgANxTZxaIja37M4xgMoYTBzhej45P7@0RGTefsEwoLcwyZDW4hBhL3Bns5n29oOCTstUJqCxnKgPPk2CzPa/GtdYV5KvBWiQuggCUGPQFjMD1vu2FMu9UTNQioEzb4ngehTbhG7S18GeTUB@AragIDsPNNCCZSWJjPCKx/bC08CF3RLcN04PIefZljzuhtPMhzNwoD@n@KedquNXMnf9FOINgluaLdtEgjBmMSASTzLRy6GZDiGeBq7bXzH2B63AXsCe@7uj32B3f/7CPsq9x3ur32Ku/UhqdVtA5mTPWdyTnB3SyqVSiWpVKoqmTZBfhs9S2b33xeWjzdUPSxgYTAcbHATJGlYb2CfUIWKB5DR8@I9@ES3qC5FI3sWsFOKdmj4lYtL2D/OUMRILISzLGxM61I4lqixfLygxBwySMRlwEdLT5nIFs2QoKZ4@rJpdqgTLXrp@BIEQibebffe5AoofvFQ0Letp6N1sqgFcnOsLRA2NYXlBWpnJezC45leoC30WnJ6SFYFs@2TVWX@f6riVSJWk6L5zMaoRIC8trr66jnYyVao4pkfhc1rSHL@HF0PYH8fgQwnIan3gXMrh65KjxjgCdKxab0aMImCIOrMWFNibafFyMQPcGG9ECCDscLxusBkrY4YJ3CbDZ1XJBM6ZZlqgzGEdUN51ExR/@Hp6nBCfra@@T9eHw82zISmgw9olX/QH4ZB5JVnRFExPqH/avxbMBz2KBv7M10jlDS5MT3pbEfedmzwyq3CRDpvM1vSkt5JbHbrKl0DVULqRQ9vCEXtXiGp3svkC2ZT9yr7ZbFEMfxaMV2kPbQdY@6Z7/SeQoDmYNJL4PJBPnwvwg34Dzi4CiSQibz50kQb51nciCIgNdfo/hZpFirn1nyy91thw@9hSA/XfhEK230JBUkLWz7ac2Zp1nOFWHlALhz00lDKtTOeTUXhGyp0EVIcBPcmfjcWLPTUUJaST9zr7mfz67m1txa1rueO3Ova2wt3qVG0BSy@fu86vBneNX9t969uW6IrBn@9HDcmv/8mxOpr8QrqWnnJ8Vvza8UsBb98A3/Xxdscca5E8B3Foj23hfD4LjkhFkW0Dy/MC75HjTbNG@ghkeBSsXStuBBd7EbF69raRbFXzBWua72LAjr5jZaLo@X8cho/vIRVFOYYPpmvjS5wTTW1rkHvVuAVo3QVnHQNEeQaAl8O/GGnv186/BDTxqEAgCowaetNCnW@HXQOrdnQ98TrBXdpqSZzBXKshQKSNUdeQXn0aSd9Mqpjmh3ADHrFBWk2HNPfiWPN5bybwahPKSpMH7KWuO/cW3PKjSlHGgXIUuuoYH50KXo4jvKk8WCIv07YijqTZ3Etj76TjgGihiVpOrTPbRt9ChFR6ctVu7BCL/AbV4gEXod7T8XE5iZdjgusFnqkxUNTDn9IDhO5C3zEAxD4GdBpA1ZBkntIbh8WNB/f8/jAX0hHNSI/GTKQt0hSxBQ0/xbfyL@Jym8CAZjwcyxzeVLFKSUvECTZd5CUCxiNLL7xx2MGdKvkTpnDxiJsrq8YASdLcaIRVivJBN/n7pCcTCv4J1uQydPbVDN0foezE0nonFq@hUhL6lJK2sKfblQsbRTLqGIqs0GKuWepgZou2B4dBDCsJmIn6HYBaabFXEQOfCT/Xln/sq4/rGGdFxp5Ts9MpWdi6R6nM1JRLg8W@CjThpnJTn2L8j0IO8rmTtVVFCS8eNDTDQ9Ekihv4am8oTfq1ztR5i3dlcyVOmEzlpAxUr7O6H1OmY@V0Qyu02ucLvl7Rfa8xjKW9328fvy1ZAcFZDwrbU0SXOr1Ot13vGjpFGQzG6gpBBfH/ia240EpfTDldAISHOr5adhuFSMoy3k149CYsbc239ueFDLepZNosBfj1MCaMUYMKlGdy0S4MTksQj2UPG@AIJjIaEKN3C1VeCILTwywmGteVctekFMDHJqWHOJF9Iu8xz9qsMeRU/lSsxPnGPMxN569m@MEokl33p5Npvhsgu4i/FE26olVJKp7koQ4e5I4NLTAus6AfbBbqAaf1/OEOVGomWKK7jpFUjrKkFfs@1gXYuKD9c/skvXBBxl70A3GooTbDJ@8sKyYg/soCEchxnaiWDThzWDQxVNHEvjuyIVaBgpZWcXjlgiisbJ7VgUtezi/i0/SIR0KeeIIId@hgUiUEN602@hMhh6w/TucWlHj0hl5Vqk3YYUGjJlXK@xmHoibkE9NYbffNpHgnuPRg5QOB34j8CyQ0UKQfixuaovHt9Sno98IRg@DJW3Dsv5y02n8uvMBz3Pf5HOv8gbJbuVxcM579TpysAIiqYSVHIixq/nXlmWcDTf4bDiDAF2xjwv9Z@DN4Dbo9QKrBCsGZQxBaA2D4W3Q9CzrONCHwAgXWRlPJtEPu38zbLByB4QuH5gRvYRDl4/DgMPwF9dnPi5u0FmZa@GhVXTaDF1922kiAZXHSauPp8N0YIFhApgeWOg6GAFRlhwRR4nOniUuJLtcoyIKqIFxToyzCU2GXn/UaUDPkCbL6gIoPgaJKus1E5hAfY2uj87B3iwE0D0mooBCQB0lPYWDJQ/N/xAOQjZMnbH7qmeyMPv1aazAcA@GHZh9IwJTr1AxA3fo4JOPlaqoHu2dfCkdlwU8fzo@@lzZLe@K7TM648aDcgprKz4e7cPsok/T@dT8CD7YpSqUtCnBKh2eifLPn47L1ao4OhaVg0/7FYAG4I9LhyeVctUVlcOd/dNdOn0HCOLw6ETsVw4qJ5Dt5MilWlUxKyonjvbEQfl45yO8lrYr@5WTM6pxr3JyiJXhqX5JfCodn1R2TvdLx@LT6fGno2pZYMOs3Up1Z79UOSjvelA/1CnKn8uHJ6L6sbS/n2jo0ZfD8rEgIwGjldtlwLK0DVtYrInauVs5Lu@cYIOipx0gHiC474rqp/JOBR/KP5ehOaXjM1cCrZb/cgqZIFHslg5KH6BxVvoZqkC/7JwelzH@EVKierpdPamcnJ6UxYejo12idbV8/LmyU64WhLV/VCWCnVbLrsA75qhqgAHUgnR43j6tVohulcMTWDNOP6G9gwOd/AUIA1iWoOguERjNILC1QKSj4zOEinSgDnDFl49l@H6MNCVqlZAKaFGxc2JmgwqBiCdmM8Vh@cN@5UP5cKeMyUcI5kulWnagwypVzFBBg4wzYB2o9JRajf0EePEjMKulONel7hSVPVHa/VxBzGVu4IBqRXILkW3no6S5h9FwDSVKp486A//aVKy0pj/dBhhcclojM1tHoyMm7RztlmFFlsGq7CjhFFad9UQoJTMNVhqdCK@xkDXN4PKmXe/0Wn30MdXFWPFxHbZdvKzFwTsrzq0n7sSQ@hUqkErV659LddjoVut1x/2ekjE0nish1eBP5XJkGzHuPu68UfGzscF034wRauulPOgkQz08gMCcTP2XbPrmXweOyGabgSyGzvsIWKmOQj42ucKjFJgaydkRL9aIqiTNBL13JDtQwbQC7zXqqCdFy0jK1A/hT@8@euHFwfgAszOru7JZ3MQSGp3fA1UNV0IhEeiPjEjQaVGVXhgEv7bTObM63PN77X6/mXYcVYbyjmAf2E47zxS/DNqJ4plkeUKWjp1lGP1Q7btJhNHnz5JkQvaLN6SWpfFPfUQ/jsKGYz6g1pSqImW1VFqmX3JxtEhyhQxtge4V1Mko8x2Ufq58wd1cbuV1IfH9o/7OYwvtBTEILSx4NSp3QT8fLzgDDDCKxQEk6cgIGdmsUUbZm@jMd5DxCjPddZpo@QNr9VVA6zqQBATZG79r1omr8bAzNrGHefjDcelg@3RvD6ZOxPb1@uqbtYKlw2797PLvGdZDkWIp6tgA1nGQ0yjJGCU7IPjQSDFiaUfsTwyczWJGDLGuOo0@YpwHbbcRt2TCiQybG@ItMz000bMDpIMtKADHvKX4debIlAyQjjXVwdZc@2MS8X2QlYgHpDFLd0K9NsY/CFsPfzXEdYMkA0kWo9i5wLmwu6B5z95TpqK0uaHAPZjFsxUfcxg3TQNSdZH9LHrX0pvkbaMXQzZlxPFK3U4lAYn5JBZC2VX0eGR/ojgjUgFM0cPgy8@S3@DxTAa4o3B3fjgqjapAxj1dEvXUkTJaNromIV9sFaGLXr7UNW0K1PI7Eikae1KdrAODGKOBUMFbQ9DGNw64oOOIJKskC9j3i474xpyKwTsQTkFyrHwHzp3VHAmloOKHyHcVlUIwLB3khKl2p@uwVJYzHcdCkTNGph@iB8H/E2kyA/4m7DgBekQtIwjgd1GSoDKtYPtKROncqYMG43Qjoqb56SwC82B2zJVumDy9GbN/DZBA9s5EfTijsIet9AwCIJOjYsMcv9ok7cqHrdN725HF8Zyk17gepIVcK9RSMQU3s3bhktjlqrMVfHGEw7omo8J9KCre88btkkY9bJkSW3nxIrQZnKPif2SXSAGiBzxx6RVbrSY5KydHmZoHZKglY8Fp6ohJIJY@PHpqtySMEJmxuV@efClCAegtxGe6nXT3R1@weW484iKtxOKEouBhPHDcJuPiI0PWXZIhZjdAOC@apAzB60FGd7hAdBk6heqLoIn0CzIUwUoiq8MoziBOt44HpKVl9U5jT5pJ5FCN/WmPA9EHrNVSOTwO8CExNN3lPXHgTwDl7vc1m1ksu1Ttu2i7iJWxWkKWx6tQGv3@EERHH9sNOLqdieOJL1LpEPTCm6GMXwjrWWcoNRJK6IdqUGzi3TstMxwDnlALOyP0Vmh6xB/UpOsALUQ5PMk4sybSwLyKR7eU0rEzXs6L9GaUsgk0obCkRMRNsSbu7zkXE1SGDA2Igp1Qby7IZpPqwXMHPfzu@sNfce1HEajXDJo6MqkBknSB3EmVHsV4bIy46YN@SBoN6ArUgGhK5FmRpg1VYY1@I9lJ2jXZUXRMjF1KLfnj9WgmVdZSUFHEuLJ2YL61DHQmUmlFhgbVwULzK6uEyqwN18OjmzGKFho/thb2eU9PKRssRBRfKNERn3je1E9n@CSV/MUXIY4e@IJn3FIERYRRZsVz1el5jvBDm4IvnWDYNHWiIMk0/QGq32jr0@8RLyrVoQz71/BHYTCBHUAj2xlnCUY9/VP/qlff6Xf9dqff8WGfhmHcxzzj4eOEHrHD2sP@XUi3/FBC08jUnETPHF@Gw7Dhuz6XLBihucJRMEibZgqj4aR0xWEiSHOORoDRbZHE34NkjDRd5vVqVMiK@5@SPV7eKTxa9lV@VmE@0UcAcoLbSlhQsA/piByTDOfTwlSGy6cyGDheiozwnUcs9mIYvwUS0TFMDGOFzJRZgtkI3Jk9inGtOXabFINwiIGWgt0Ar5wJ0/TZ9fFeXphF3qGlwIbIr@eMonyKMsY4hPgweZzcK2/@ZOwBgR9AP/9qFrfMYgSa4loq2lLI@xUZZRRwIfPADs3RNBPDLNZpwyrUjQGtj5NQ48mTx6hBlj8gFMkwe1NciSMyDRsfvDguXYcppz5xcFFZFIsOxe1AEaQ0SuceZ9jgOftZGvx4iMuaM5yYdiTktIH0Y6RqAJXwCtKEea2JMsdUfn7ErKx8b68lCFicZXJmXLWbtpXkQh4oHV5f8VirP4TJ2E5QT5p6LIaj/mDxO6n36NwxMzLbLFo3HOdZQ2BmtiIslktNIm1xgo@TgpXEJ8E0cYqRpRnwEG5f6VmzeZKI42Idx1uxPnmGDo/RLLKb0ouK7u8mj31cFG/RolctNHpIEe4YpLSgv9fq0PD64zOIhMnbqzrNGHWcMuoTfjRAJcikqfT9FCLuk7gn6NEEymG9TaCd2T@PEjVpJKdCnqqkWJBLpCcGbkenTZiXBi00vsAwcSzh6klKC5xjd0JHefnMJQYZxgQGiFJxkIn0UKzBjTorwUd0O0ArXUdroTzORPC0ZVo46KD/mmAUlV8qd6TFQ32SyV8UGNJYQ4JdBeV6CpLyN4fXWn1MUKZIAUN8Bil0i6bmpqvvb9WPtgXyAQQuTcnS0jfnYmMcsQzYwB8zqT5GGTiqSpaMjaj4QKjT1ABjAXYp7W7A21WU/jpD5ni0bpDDCDYQ/DmNP8uyBIbzXstpamORcXOCWRxJbh5tjshscZGIofgdyS@HIou6tHEFAAFjDOWLeYCAYU0JezwUoNA7JufFEJV9BAWLeRyW8JGiokZ2njPSkagyw@tVI0duVo63JozMTCAgWMzOEyECMsvsLBEUWOhm4mLkeDO7PVEOEIgV7zPFoStkr8RpqHuOCUi3EOecaEap5YWbkxxMia9XnVii5m9KfZszUnPJVKCPxrCWySdT13Ox1Fi1KyvxorGSQA/HrDWWCKRwTIT1rPBj/8g1xQx5rm1CjU1GTMqQ9tl4SzTsMmHf5v01FJvklK1kDAXP9AxX2686X7ESC8r@dAB2sUhHBhi7/YdbqyxTFSbyrgCKS6ecXdK8ISSJ1calHpuFO10VaU8HKFB72n5LfD7Z24uFfb2cKEOj62C4msvlkIkvzeD3yrYaVUmdfjaeO9u66Xazg7ufhp8vszT3BwFdCbChdtABdAkMitDrD9t8MwTiAFkxd0Y6suJe/6bVMq9gwBNK7DzoNs4poyEIWoA62ujl8wkpgAikXGB/wQZi@34RevTd@SxoSijqGApKo0nwra1Oz4A8@KGF9tn6pIqA4cSsrJlg3XKKW99wBcGbTaizKHyx8y0yT7Y/Bt1u3xVf8J5gjBQw95AssLdnFshxFjxhJO/em5Di0boiuO10Db9izGLyOoJTC5O6Z0LFhcfY@MdBuzwepO3aVxuWFWjyMjZzGeNTu8Ju244MFv8dYJkPAe3vyn3tD9INolMyMyz1cgRHT4DRq7w7c@8Ty@KQTkzS7PncSNTZ6HoUrAGa7pAsoGLZU/dSSx7Jrolrn4/zLaRhjmFInDDmyveVQFezP29avB21Wt83K9I1ANyxf2hG5JtQfmxCpDMAGoFy@AE9MYr2v2RgWO8lAoqwgIOXdUzPO1igjgUs60Wj@NtdulQqiYXB8rIolbbhIZMRpe2S2MUP29tiF9638f1lcWV1tcBz7q7zDT5uq48PYhtgkIZzuXE13IVXSCui3xhaa2MXL2SLC25hoV7c3CqE2VppG9364ekf//Yf//j3/8yW5Mt/48s2vdS@6kye52UXGt8WXj4U8L22e7G4cFlbGFwstgvIZf@kqOH9yijjR@aj3vDSSvEqYHwlO1K1z6boM7KoULf6XfvDX2F22RCpRphNya8h3xxFc2yqERjfA/SjvIQtvLp0ILmVByRSAHSC6njonUaABniw3gAlARe0A@XyfLaiFPcYDkZn0KcqKRmJh2TW2wB9WqJICuiLCytWptMLgx5qwG9J5uXmWZYPv51RXfJv9utB2N7uj8XSeVos5cSSK5Zsm37ya2/hq7OQ7aB3LmeD7YBtu5ASHS2gmaEIOyTo0f6B7tpJkNuyFujKHoSkwlRQZvaCc/Xuj5xl@MK1sG3N4aWZglUkdMiERVLfFnoP0C3fIMeDHXO1IUGhLncxVJlxoqL7F0UgP2RDgKjmaybIRh@qxJM@8kjGp6z6IvvaotuECDCS9fjDHo17/ABr0UJP2jzH9lJ4zRGZz/NXXBsL7AxNaGMK1x8hQAcqvJ3MkSfhYmrRYitvo5XUTPbCNtsnmY9tHSbBSNmmc6F/FQYTsDW3SbiFnvRrkYbcfLwi7I4@XjGqspO238IyilzfdEedgXRXoNpxQH3TtT3wSMIeJUAMh2P2b0yPMFIUqEhRiW7hy7ImotnHpvNI6EnXdOhgx@OTI4MI2a9pGNv3ibHtZMlLRLED8wAhpU35Wn6nG8qoK0MidtsfXuLtgH6LLlQb8bkZ6fPwmtQExv2WRtojyGRyHo1naEpqMPTb174rUof9k6E/qcCyBZLPqOE50EIMwYRI4OCTVc9qnkKYWyS7hCiim0KWQ3h5QXcir0fjvrW1zwl2qRoKMuwKDoIYOxElg/tYXyXoGHH1H@gEE@WpyVufRsoplmZetDSSkGzTbYaG2dTQsVQN5tjRA8e2GFU9MhUvyEI3uNBe08EvzORdjBEg67alF6B0RVh7i/Xj6tQOen5scRp0LeXony0IXhdxPNNVlGyNZKmbT/PRjXeIFciRX@NRIHhtUuGMrLl0eu48lNe5pcx1hIJ8a1v8rC86@gI6usCMPEPEaa/Dk2VihYruwPBEhSz/AUKr67cBv8mdP0FWPE@l381nndrX897FUvq8d3/@u0OYyClZrbIZkZKH2WrGkmMFVsasG3tVVmmhCjV43otnOO8J9mExSACIZNO1r9mL@ywgdJ7CO@XPU0yQWJchJtmn68si@OwUmqk4FtmUNecsOarz0@/yjoC1lX6xD/mDw7@AhdpUkpoe9jnDFoAiP93fbtjlJMyur@Rer@Rfw06oHYwzw@AG19tMeHMZjEGUCHE7C0vP@e8xbogR4mEc@gX4OIZ28rUm7HsSSiclOYXKYU71WJqtoIzHPAH5gcoULhVdXBydx8fDR9zwuwJYTuWlWFBsOmhwXxrXz7B/jfX4Ic5rSe8Q5ki0MmAbEVKhZhCyunzlMQ511HBZJD8nT@xg7FYCAt2bTRmrRa/fy0hhzfEWCyhEo9dMdz23nkuO0akhGhuhC1KYWpwX@a13b/7@X0e/pUaprZXslyH8jlK/pdbWU/wID/D2Sr3dprZSm5ht7SE1ycIeGB7f/P1/oPzWTwAHUyab8GdrVcFam6S2MkUqcp/aWoOH/MoK1Pu/f/sbtGGBd2x4F@tC3RWEWEFRZMfvEe9CuqhgK3lbuhhNK@SYhTDYwhD25vCChlHjlfUcqelS0qriNpCRr5Q9ilziyTBrRKZCrMlQ9hQgGXGBIlaQYZDKhKIlDNsNZbaBzBuhKX554a2FsAP4RZpz6Cq16caLEE2GFnhbBB2Y5hphP88PW7l3tjbv2LCVTUlBiZC4tZNz7fqrwv8B)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/uhmnv)

Lolwho.Cares code:

```
*1220 *1220 *1211 0 2 2 2
```

Path:
[image]

`1220₃ = 51 = '3'`. Ternary unicodes are placed on the stack, then top two values are swapped with `010`
(standalone `0` is expanded to `010` if x+y is even), then the values are printed with `201`
(standalone `2` is expanded to `201` if x+y is even).

One space in `"  082"` is to fix Fission – atom is teleported from `0L`. Another space is to fix x position of `0` and `2`
in Lolwho.Cares.

Note that `,`/`` ` `` (turn right/left if TOS is zero) only peek TOS, they do not modify the stack.

Answer (score 3):

## 314. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE8), 14500 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=x-UA-Compatible content=IE=9><!--ss
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,+i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media \0 all\a{:after{content:"314"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:>Ex Cr Uitharbody$/ $5"c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]p 8ogr34*61  prstd6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\/a4on;z op>s'0}e}equ7+?4[0]tfc;[ ]  
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39cyPbdRj4s9r5Iy4bfAM0gW6gG98AAQ6Hw3mPejPDEcl58yQQD9MAGkAPgW4MGiCB4XBKUna1VuzNOorskuXET1birLxOVbypzVre2EmV/WvKlZ/8B4w/trZcW9Z/oD3n3NuNBgmAHDmu2traJtF9P88999xzzz33u2l6vZ//PIIPe@b2Z92@O2Zjyxuz9sg@t0YaezBj903byxppScJQu6PuZGA5Y68kRZjOmDc2R2PWN53uxOxaLAKuBpvbO3Z/bI0SzLMs1rT67gX4pxlzrAt24LTsNkBiY/fMcuw31gj8Mow9tPpvB2/HrOUOBqbT9thwZDtj8s0y9swES2fSOmNm0xuPzNbYdh3wyjH23Ombg2bbZBR8OLJ4pDwDUK0zirPoU2DsiTvyLEjBbVme56JjERzNke0@3n368bXweop9bAJSw741vZa8rrMXtjVqX49hsM9OHj267ppmn6quwx7dREnPsN3J2D0YX4efZbtdyzGZoRU147pnDog5tvqFVCG14AV@j@wRlKYpSq00LxlnMmhaIyC@KMILe9zTIMKJywnOXKc/Y9YUgAGOHQhmjZmNpcWyqRSGhP9jq@U67Tl4cLIADsC1BsPxjKnMcQUPgJc7Yt7QbFlq2@rbA3tstVnfBuzcjsDGY1Dg7MyaXbgjKHiVsyIh4g2tlt2xMYrIgSchsz20mpMucyfj4QTQ81jb9sxmH4I1Z6xtdcxJf5xgTfAD4pH7Rc9yBEq208V8vJi7IAQHqgDHflMH2tj9PgN0zhAdTNpj2@hxge4YtGkRllYbQe3PyQWQzL7n534x4YVkMN6zkdsdmQNg1LZFNPjs4BnzWu4IbPDDsLwWrAPTMsdse5tF958@jLJqQEZt1JQCklbYJWMs4nuyc7M/sTw2MGeQtjOGysVcKj8/hgTBWXQjWmLRdJoZKZbJsAxUtgIzsikGVaIIBqi1RlqHX44ZBZbRge@z0QSm0xmZXbtvcShdt99BQHnkWCPLDHinMtEE921RGnmWLrBcnuWzLA/vIisakAhCzDC9mIVfDn4AoQgY6PBLZ3hKAVsgO0EW2B7rmAO7P@PQh0ME32JZneUBIqCpA2SjABCKBkJYfMLwxj0gbM88B5Bq3z5DcWEFEgNLKwmf5NZWkkQWykaepNez@n1MFQgFJMoWWB5SzUGmM5Ay0NEoGH7muz3KPuGVT8EPcMxDjgtA3hRQKoWkysMP7CCGDJA3BggXA@SFoYO7AeY0QoVwOfDLQVnlAtIabaItSFeIqyMxUaDoSAOIxqDo0hkGhZeB4k1j8WbTDPAEBPI5BjKloLNChhXyDMhVTDEgvQ7IYNnrIMt0QEJHYFCkOpSpDojowCw6ANXTWSaF6Kqn0R/ipiEukEDPQJwMmKFc9Bz@IB4UvA5J6pCmYRTnrAW4GVnIZDZNPGfkoPDy4AfEMgBXA7jFAGyNAvhj3AIQroAsmfcJYfaHPRNpASWAjAysBgTJAk4EG8KD2cinOUtR6KY1tlvSlQS1ireAYYnjSw@UACBNmMmwAQUGnHNPLJCACgikRWE18aw@cBHIkJYJZmRbqO0oOXw49lhDOQvNlOWeY0NK1X8hGY9ERHOErSjIq7Y1GjEMC42tlyBh4k2anvV6gm3tHK8OSCcLBGvHtPsBAlR1zDG1A/CNepDebBHtzsgdUP0aoLDou@5whdgF0XSBgD5xL6w56nPJZQ6HfZDn4G4BISZmH5C5MEkfIHUhnCpHCCJhvFbPBoCUFMhVe2S1iPYi6xA7DRJ4EcUSM6r30gjlQahZSLOhC0LVwzjOpN8vQXNntVi6mmxb50l04U3HYpOBOPiNCbSHAkTThLacGlPEIoB0z9ComTrxS9ZzB4tZ4@LlIMh6z8YmoH9hzqD0OiBZrKk5AI2DYbPuQMM9AI7hJYgl4fGG54C1XSc6DqBcjKB5hUwHOQGQfaLJ2B5YoI@5EAVLPENIo3AjzJozYGWiVkYjdYxjco1QmnSdUNwhE3LglQUatvakhVTDtG2HOAgaBI9aqyrA5UqnhgaociPLbPNgqF0gRiH9CFo7C4guVIEWAUINxXI80HY8jdmoFgLDd90O8Bg10aBqQNR5Oi3KO@Y8cJpqLU0iSiPfDM76zGat4ZCBO@gngNajVAHaWPeVzd6AZ7/nsX5rMhrN2HQIBWAPINS45XY6wLRvrGEPQLBBm7VmLaiVkEtkGqntkgRqDa9lObBtWhDGsSDbe8@@zroWUBta5A5gSpw@z8BwSFkgUpgOb60dEyiFWWgNZ0QWABPE6Liuhu5t1/KIR0CbCWo8JuZZXaoRUL06cxk0QO0DmBM0AgdYFgSOqFUIHxOUlmYGkxKF/7HlQI1pATNCXYfiQ310l3VA9w811qjcma2WNRwL9nBJitlOSKE5fIQKDbmqApjm9aTN@6CLLWAgQVDJ55xQC26ekXBFRZ/0LBNFrOhgQJvuWIEKy7hA6c9uJA8hzq@lLr/EMAsYvJRX4DCkmoDaHcmGyRglCApFu9VDEThGIUNaBlSy0eRm9sEtnPxowNROkDZio4O0kbRk4IR4rIahwq9/E5A27COs6oIDBl1wuAW06Q2WQHYDJPvtsKuWNDWQhbcBHbiOuwQqEDOAi0EWfagsiBmPUWqY/YAZqbp4C2WEcnre98X2C5rO4dAdQc3gQmeGkowXWYi7XN5PiQVNhAL95sUWFVqKKLbz4zHvcw370A@iKoY1FfRJEyQFCDHeAwCZ5/IUQwhTrSdYAr8LkvicmaAJdRwLVVJzNONAIHvQKkNCM2aPRiAGz7Ft4E2P34ZoxKfQFJjtNkpWJAfV@@uJa8jRe5OmPb3ezWiho/bKk87NEetgD2MEugZUoli040WVMrlTzJCXnHSH4yRF5W8ZAlIgDYo81oFOCzQEj0DQHM@cVkxeqGJygsmTcacgK2DAiFw1Y181h@Pr2L0CN2SawRnUa7KVWRdabVWFt4puhAl6JDX0MEegXkAlBC27WGw3TfYWpMeIqdM9io1qIX11LROkZTntIC1BCMQlnF@NJ@GNWmRQQ60a5gCDU86pkVgg4B0pQRFlcEgmRfuJDqTkcT9SZ7jjxKHhARbjGojCLgMVHRqAGCFjg85ht@xxQ2gp9@75@spGpQLMBkoUiM22Elbu/XEUDSQ1BNZICRGJaGP3eIx1I6ZAfjHwFccGtCXg1EqVXY57I6hxZL@SIBCQVXKQk33CinJ@ap9N2tcL2kFHDCRjrQNdyW6N5bIEjT@vDZV1VI0uUBWU/yhSFZkX4xPoG8xLrligsgg2sjzUeisClVAJxxADwatLScSjCrc5Q@/NWn2hEnATVHYujZqA/pnoqQeCKCF0Ar/S3qipHAhWBw6HPds9@aQi6iL3TDZtp7Tg0HdbZp@cNzG47Md9fPDgaPfo640lMPp2s3TdIWlnCjlsaidTtetMkhnNKG2GYcwBP2ysh40RF8PIkvBmqjsNqUqzFjQuU5@ch0efXicJaEJIDkoBzPi7ptLwMKB0SU3T611rhFk3Hockgyh@WKYeMB9mYEDU0d/08Xk2efMGC@86UkPhjpj1JyYH4DsmDxw/noae1xQw36vZ4S0ixQUt1HZw/HNuCof08fkYtebryJAqHWKZjw8f7R9VCGzP9M6sfl@lIElvDLqUOWprwPP9SduSloUB8QemFotrc8RRnyZclxK41Vog8Lxs2Qr4AAC7OJrL1P7Az5rXA9z3rueNXNVWwAFkJwjX9cqwPtT6UERDeGAT18Ke7rJWlDzmjVXgtLTFCnwXm61WNmvlM8Vws9Wap9kOAx2QUmy7vt44Aq8zT0UXba5FCrVaoH/8@AbiHimR0BVQfcy8PtMoLa8vYe9FtVnUS@5BD83tW9oLkngyk5VkMuoPfGotj/qcofD7U3scSyn8qysQFlLf3T0wHvqBxUAdDWBQpwG74NgyjTo40dDygEcct@92XbYFcbh26CcIatPKbO52XedGCZnoiFmN4MwFyF8crzGH0NbYb6jjSLHC3VU@62E63gVIaT2XRiIRhQhUksJrr8xzE8g1z/fxwTf2oRHRs6lUYE7RAyQIxSFyoakVciUHpkJCmsBnaQaDWYwbtd33UEPTCJhpIeiCiLtz76WOJDG15NLwS1H6qnuD4q/c2TXWAhfOWmAIkezg6bPHB0/3n@x@fjo2stkFeyZVzAHhIL0m6EJaj9MNa@sWr5qYLQQXgboxwuoFUmACHRR/OHzijUBwaxhE4wis4Bo@/xP7qttzop5yPTMX6Ku@clqchZ5g5eNBRUToaLf72BkZ8WkzbM@Rf3rj8dArJZNQy3uTpgad1uSrlts3u0mKBw1Dv5/UsetycIjjGt6yGICMN7N4DD6mBarDjAYOzf7Ahc4LTcWhaGAxDp4Gq/p2twd9YZyvs0aKFnAw5SbZhh4C9JWTQd5IAJMNaCu@fjnJnLW/ohsFztd6ysgkZT/YQvWHsBsdC7pOMWitgBTKNSs7vXd6j81ASiOk60AiTNsSUzbYFvQZKJI0WIr9fJ84JC1wmBRlBdHo9QQHcUFKJbOpTF7PZZPQLYNuGuisKg61qQNz3OqpY1cFeKrboXGDEBd2vJbpdLQtYfCRBb3vI8hquvbF6alTBwX99B7hhhNhtVm9pteVMrsZZUuEV8rAvQvZQ971HYB3yQisSV@2Qp61zZvirG1S7Wqz5HgwFG2OOmRPdkGReuOCvG5b4bqHEZJhz@TWQtgkBn6XXDIg1MeoEr6QUkmoUNDSAuslES8VlF5UD4FzQG6FIrD5aAbPB59@DskR7HQj39tu1KOxetRrcJDUGwIRaYy5hVLaw/HBMbSOAeejlIbCRSHNLqwoDp@bHh@khEhi0tGPD321AAINxgcD0U4w2QpMQLGoew6SA/gKR0t781FG7PQDp0GChBMOPoAG4dCkQRfkDETmGdnlGeEpkctils4c98JBaE2LFdSmPeZj/O5khJN5djucNwieNngYgEaZC8l1mvVrWi0@ysojUy6gE2iygTVwcSgBtCsSBRZlweQzhtgX9HCgGqpVSsWJE4Cvsvt7IMVaFh8vUgfYiQKW2mfR8Si5q34jaapvgJvX6FaY@d3wBDYV@olPABqJDGawaZREjICSduIOKNALGm9Bzwe@uisNZ@Me5Bg4TDYr7tByrvf5eI8wppRpnjUaBYFvO7HL6MbGRrQUrUYTYNoB0zaadtAUB9MOmVQyYTgNTRQjQSb0rVEMdKtHr2o@5KlSRx6Youbwxh7GzFqplK4nzJouvgZ@FSgKoDyEVvEDcKJKpYJGRZGrFzhVA/p7KO97yDvHrZE9FCT4KigE3C5okCYiQPcetfmRVca@6XqKDCoj6DRaqGLGRtHTWuq0fnp52o6fXkUTGFspmxXoH4LwGscGWnfkToaguNUyJRVkm1JLl@rlZiWaim7FYgW1DwmZivJRQYmbnNaxqAU8FTs9jQJJBXVqrd6I4E0ThqIEhAI8Ojb0Mvr9WFS7LED6TaWuxKMQV4kmQCxXolGgSwuJ4FGmcUSAM9EjewqkhIoJTVx4ToEEJM1JYXX9hjXszUbhAMGoG2jZOII@n4yHykBSPCwl3/D4YYVuoafv6708HCi3OHiH@tJwxqW7xDE9TS4sDPHb3XO1M3DHZvIzDTpNWqi5jG5Ek6oKLSH5cEiU7Se2h1XYdCx34oVHGpcOgGLq4HrSm4Cw9FfNJICr7KFktXoui27eB@gsmObBpgRnrFQ@7@UDaLc0@KEQRa0EJ0tAu6DlJDbIRVxqwkdldEKCix5/bD6bG77WgtTKFIelMCG767gjSwWSQAyJFn/QUiGpysSKkgMa@boxLyF8qUnDjrdtgUR81HdNoi0X16H5oOEgFB/65xDlyGpLfZAfHRCPGi@LkdVObkk0OeuOetBCQG5QEhtBaQ2ER9L1hm1tPIWoUgwb3LAn792B0nnB2oZh5FrZTsn3Q64AYvegkLBX6kAX1/dSdfBURCHv82Ehv4/@9PDhPh87ocYWm1ccR2sM3PYE9ErRbzqynG6C7QM/2Y47sIEMfvw3Z/0j1x3zXj5YVo3M8E6zPZj0TRrzuT4sszZey226fRoKWhd1Hn4y8sy@yQehfN/dz56Arv/85LiilUKBkub5YG3aOA65PFlOz4PwnCNNs/rTQx5nTHkzK2O75S9GQzEjPHLoMRFL0aCMfPc8uvtVCudQhHsB3Qe4DA10ZTGKQNbAUQQsUkBcmoYreoTjpZ66QveVfbAgnE7huOI4x/ZSN8j9fNzpLDinyflMRdHUnztnyJkvUVvoI4ZRyvJAuF5tIUwYUI7CBMvWrocTwitYYtCz@v4M4hEoJjhLBm17H9Un6JugJs7XjlmgSA9xMoQkNE6xsRbomt6NYQuoU0OVh5YiG1RPoA1LouYibSaZGOIuU01xXDE16XHp6ULXnkZPtqt8whq7TiPea0vywffNBoDYrpb91USrgmFK0WgQjKASbhCDsknT9jeyGizC8GhMXaIoZclLQq9haqTU02l@v570iAgdJp@eTj9KGZ9D5wPXfG3eS3atMia3klpk5@PQrR6IDRafLpIMymHidNx@W@WTXlD@jHeXsCDEUoNg1RkJfHCxR/6CMxsXsYiFgSAuQ2vVbsC9VnTVmwFCq9sCQFAbLtnbs8T5W1aDFuxc84Z9e1xnV9rYbfQw8@PJyLm@Do6rlKOROfMksVKlwnaPPv6slqpzCNLAxImsAi@tqb@MEvRg0HtwtSqYcL3N2B5Tw04LC2zMr64BUlOa8wD0AQZPoMyChESOEPW31tt5XjoWdDxjFmLuzQYJZilXWqdvjseWw3mLzyauJjef9hHJVCj5HTGHUGIpmmgBRdNGP0CxzI5PHu4fHWnAoV4suo8TMiWodmarB/rGqkz7lAxnvsQ@akfZRxhHwV64BFUKOhMNER@YtwzMDd0JSB1FQdcaxcBRwbmUFjjT9BVF5AqXIBCummqNiUYBsJilQJ4IWGkp/s8d3nMSeJZYlMWJkkDu2L0S0NZWtIljv9Y8aDdIDYUgUd73pCWylc0Yia9NXSH@GdkDnAuGLhNpgZCHWo1tgHSj0DKrvGNf1FJqsR7fZPV6mc/wQ0TU6WnJrVi@aQp68ukwEpAC5wPRK@tcW8Trp0AjtxiL46cDz0qCbwHZ0aQ5u1lL5U1DVgJk1TfgwD3l60guWWTKUfSXNpEIoZVQiyuaFtdLhbL1nDrZ1xaHQ3Z8BIL84DRkjOeSbVSYrig@ZhzQC3OEXecSe@Z6nt3s0@rVTt/mK8GCxrokCCMg@ZQJJ1fGikF0w/oM9QwLY75kmS8EFpQgf2pooCeFOSOHmMIukZhESgOpyN6@RQeZbRqM2EDGFcOcvld@nxbk42MXkH0sVkCHdQ4SGmJ5CoqOU0n2O2@L87/owzsGyfNrOq96LofjcZ3Tds5cmkUKTI2UpmdRzwxiD876N2N2bK9Hr4WgAQ48rLEKO2/Q7NBrSQCaTBHT9ORAw/RCw4biNJNH9KER@yUpLy5NWUi2aXUmTpfmNNHM1Ne3hFSLBQrcaTbtVUGBCLjazP8uCQayEmueoWU03a89OMADzSLIT94nmmf9@qomtkB3aKTGEEt8/8s320D/m6XTg/YKxzMDQwM0BSwptbOysERUtNBrecHyYfdJ3zaJMGS6DWTLHEGWzH5gWA6apvZVFfSNAU5UiBIH3sQX6KJr2IxjzucZ/e/yRJZN1Tkgt1urwl5b5cWTokkl6C62iQhc57ItikRClheCNeUTO6GOOwrc25Hyl2IxYmZe7r3JeMLfoA7fWoj2EH/r6qYImcqaTd2CDqnZtK01RT4yzyZtVx2edQO1OLck7Dz3NLOsglYiJpkbaFyefZ7Bkd2F5t7/rgo2b1@TF/S5jSs8Z@IN1Sb17dvcRhVhsCaFUZ@/VwWxxU6lwLCaanafXnfkRAEdGEWssUjiClY1RDT7Gpn7ZnOGqlDvw7ksWK8AEqfSisdT6RUT1sPh6vjYP6X4xeLy2FOtxemxbOQhyVfJqnxsjjIs1s3eUqrQXNkDs68a7ZBxpTBfttzhRtBgppTiWOc4T3S@tOTm1McGqTXpm6O5aQ2Lz/HwJydWjXOLZkPU5Zbbtz2s0P1VUtNfczdPC9cp0yu0rsJeRsk2dESxHVcD03Ip4LbGuBZ1BVvdQabxNaC40jbEJ5q7ilgt9wJ/KzWIHnSG@Xt5o/ZmKVZ3kE9qv9U3oSlf2SIsjDriqOYtvHphexa9lhP2bCmi41Z/qftiLfDHE8Pjg7dxtmf3XY8d03sdgbojoAJ/L@fpMC1t01FplD1sXiOG/MUT8wI1@123nyt0kya8Vpb6ZNRB0S@@dxVygZDS9VuElK8BuY4uvitF@1lydHZbAdH@rxEunA0Z17SyyySVmNRZnTvoG@CM4PKcPUoVKKaW5GOIKxLGuZwLc@Z/f4HWYxVp/dZjOCONGhQ8jFAsgGE84lr2L5JaZn1q7bsJpRtg87dlIlS4Z30L2it63yhSZqT0D4yhp1J3F1Gd/sSaWEv7GofNVxZuI17Tz7g7UimRjU0xBYCzDrjnJQj1RnQO74Q1NtVoWytMTOi1W7drM4tCbQgK@BB7z8/A8AwNN2N0nclwoVQXOmjO0XqS9YZ@lXbbC9ihz4fKocItytKCiu5Z9FvbaeKdPFx5VsmkUimhw4SmchYs6zpT6SDuK5u/FxIml3nK87A4fTcKGZenQWQJr21cKYKMVX17ClwsJh3bscYzfN9RmjZdt/8hJQVCtW2jNgbKJa3hXVdiN9QdsTuFzUcvPBzzaHZWjVvw1kZ0L4E@2G9eV@jhuaY7laaKs6kDnOlatK4fwQnNXN2WCm7nxmEhvqq3v1qXFAMiulbQ8mtrHddQ3abVN/lnmsusg1fU0mvhLQoNMQuMs8Z8rng@xx@5JpSGMyCW3YaOSs8aWGRdo@ib7VcTz/@sDDR18bfKe2pZreR032qtCjC0QS44@F6YnA4pS2PXgS7WGBcQYlelj0tUhesqCexPJy4l8sHA7Fr8jIp1knI@ZoHLdHjPbm5cPnpR4ktzWhBtPsK8miWgUp1ZM8//LgX4ZNaCcp0Mbh9xu1b5WzgMeofavmpt7M0m1um5Padn9fiC9MC2qnIAP475mSLrUAesuz1cIzccLqydD9Oz7/b7d6EnikYuKF23sxSnfdxVi1vCPgjuzGyCh/jcOn5njrnsQMPKWtOzJtAuee7YHVoq2VYF7eNYD3@vkqH@7PcvOoi0tqsPFPG/vyj8W/uWXdMdD4f0aQz7E49eFFWlzdC36U0dvuaFVlu6o672xh00NeGoiQUxNOm@XMQ07XGrh5vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9UR9uvVPfFSljM/UhOmt9G8g7mmnIL5Ww/zF@DlYVuhhA4s1aYFijrywbpKP93urQPGt5fEAUTayEY8Kh2sh3hZdoO33p9cQez4GGFkkFI7x8ZgINq3AXyzJWala0@WIuhsVyjZVcSko6KuSqlQKFR185vrSwgC5UxdJp/lqFUDiXhFFowcuHkFssKqIBQjs0dAvuC/y1sBpqaSPn9CZd76bA5CP2bVDR8LV62IIWSYdGraHNMh3xWUVmo5/E3ZPwbYDONbHWTqtk186rUDi9r5quDZ8GfKDoJivH0Pr20ONvpnZWzsaJRVLQF78@ZchpM1vemRYF07Y6fBYETbepiAOX5mlBB1FbOKePg@gozLnixQWX43ZBqKt9Ng/sh12ltixdf7S8@IM2U/38qdU1cRH3Y3uMq0CXcAWx7LJ1S7fC/trE9OyvTSBnq5gNj4LgM5Gj8JkBaFsC74nZtVufLBREgKQgsFhCyj8L7I9ON8viomd7uIYqMKwZmEKW40yMXNeAfsOSkNeH7oNTMOYViO@vXBp62fC6O5zhNrQZmdaNrNtjGmUV31Vdx1Wry9YicTEZDCee@CzHgVZphUehB2fk7l3YAFx9DaKV9cz@ePlIdWjIFbQw0SjOjau08W/YfbfLvlFIMVDaQAlD5XwJ4zyA5vkZLg0aOUs4kdK@48wnDnSoI56x11C2VpqptmOP14/mjMe4TMj/YmZ4y4FbH5KP8a3d/1AI6slyijy@Xdef73m@pX0Hzjt2J6OWhcbgIJNwt0Ckau35y5pxq4iLB7FchHtpa2dvoDl0nclYHU2cta1Cbm2rUGLTQi7EBiz2tf0nz5UwN9Ay8Nu0UAs6fxOvP5ubVq4ZuMZktgOK2Go5uhja70s85OcuHdEa5Fvi7OLhUC0S1w/dZf2dZ7ORNb5zhwmE/2Tw0GrhzOGtaT91n7iOC63REATl4MjihwksrPVYHhGjPcbt8kCf9q3JHBPYFY0Q1zbModWE8u3PTXdpizjgh@bYXNEU0dgg9f8C0628Yveb1ugVDfqFzKu6tIsIfWJNqW@xmmF4HVTHrRZXiXE8bqGOLMzYeEPXdfibpG0KPvqT9VIFmgJ63X2uXMMV/gvjAkv7Z4tZPTznC0WsNj/tYlVeR1bT7fP3mmVJjs2XBZgj2/KSj/HwBHLLZZgK2pe3Vobk18qQedcINNlz06N5@uVdjTlIffoBq4B65qjl4kyYMKxZoBM68eAWMR1sGuBrB5pA@ClILLM1EWcv3oZWf9Ac0GtlhyFUmkdWE7cbNemYkLE5vVmYfGRInJEQWtQVnCzgiyus1DkWewa9EeX2ZmuhH7VIVXtIL5LUK6fLab2O6thW642Jo2Yu0Ws@Nr3gD3lOPiXjirHqUDWiUeSkSVvol9akxdVroND0LXXcG0GfPzleN7ztn9@yZD5kMrBwknlxFmal6up6Pcqsu3w@PRCuI0sVZweCLAnOEeT6obq7UvNE8PB/@OCrSWiEG7mMf6YJiK7bZ/AB@cnIEZ@7cOAz1xt37Okh4I37DlaJE8xWFqLAh9cMNG2tygSUnjPp89GHbmjp1aBN3TGVzq9V1T6J67GlWs65SifMTW/myOW7yZK7eBjq2Gqr4oAFnGlQH/sby4Jg4rtkAjUsG3G9p57khJ3mMmIF6DLiXviSAfQtd6wOPfomh96zg8eHJ9rQ05e2T7s93I9xQ49bOLHBKKRCQ1KvzFFovpOvSGvb3jj54FhX9x4faBhgBb35jIYKH5yZW/isHPcUR4@aSXNlLwh9rfFyBfGTkyeP4/O9nyy21xu5A0sJe@8dHydwb8tXj5d6h2M/gtrRcacrox/s67qyhH2fOzQ7uEp6LklpFaQTC3qjwIyf8ANfblWuWu7Qap/MhtZn0HiiBPfumHxuZSafmud2F2shK64kFFVUVtRyGSW0OBs629Yo@K4qzzN7iNKyRZ8k/6xcjoKaQzo5Si/XHtbN@F/XYlhKrET4sEh66ia3jm0Vaka3h6ak6f19EdN1fRWdj80OlCvLriysxQDL5of77vkdppIt0XlRAyd1DFyl2rcuJc@rAxDdSXzh8LxwBGNz5TKYdQAC59zSCn9hOTPTUWkua516UYLYuKhtbZBvWHeYkApW@JzjgdBL5/iCVfUs1iKjckvCJ6NQlL29Bwe3RTgStFwf6uOnz9kz08PTTdYHDGNs3QHjuWb0SsVxKzxab@V0ansEoIy18LrD5fW5xI7NUdt1ZtPbJ@Focys27XRYcQALbRTI6ttTe1lb1eLjWs@WLzO6LW2@j8OdLejB4VNvBKD33/lnup5K0ZlG@NVT3HpLyfgVnMXQZM7woLyw18lBIBpaqLdo4KAs7Y0@tqa4HIWPBi/r1C9t33Jr2r68sro5WedXWOOXWZPeDT90ZGktpa8BmF3jx7Ja4P3Y7V/0XG3PHFneHcskhBrPEt/idDRxwofueglxbALfmcj3inmafzJyLObE44qyePh@eGcc3xOGR7Px7VwQ9u1btiF2bYFHsJFN7BXDE5xAhbRwh6VEIHALX8ypVPRske3gEfglaCAUShGd6JwcP60a27wUW7BKJf0Kt6HJJZmJLXLBsZf86EaAi4fOQZ6YeqazzTH4bPobuBgdPs7eMlI6oZXTsymwacnwjtqy2NkGKG1ePjt4tn98snvy/LiWql/Jiti/yXFzHEjN39n7UbotQ94F2YCZ@UGutAO0D8nRweiorHp@vhjk7FrWKgtZm2dK3sE4m5eOk0zSRsakegX4qTJPjXyhZUInDtvPMZWP2Ida4vv/@kRSeZODlilNKLMSSy1LeGh6HmRL@F@/moF8WTqNvjxhcfYmsGvXddsiRc9itz9@io92Dx4/P9pnPoJzprmw2@NepZjlR7OiwFctKKeOTWsiKiwqokShrCqV6KMoECaqRVmJto/SsajA5xDMpw5uPBWxt1hsk@ADBaNBoST/yzeTV1ENl/cpEDbqIxVlgvIYgJ3glrA/@0mbHxvuHwTh3z8yGpB0ow33ktjuuWKzJ1KUKuZw9S0kdEw37esMzgef3@wi0anxwJUXdIbTtfN9FDpyg18pI45f8hMiBvGPGsZxIjxKCTq55zZu6uQ4dPBko0VWxqllOs1LY7t4xQrwPDPp6HpAfeKM@ekh4qyBCPCRFgiUBNskZPlB93IoYHR7A1i5aXVth3kOKN/WuMReAZ/hWEyJ7yxW1Wr0RhQfNL9bR@2NB/1QwBtHIXnJ03Hy/a99N9ktMzBPUw/A9ivC1gHzr3LzF0ks65vHJc3TDyOBR5wJrHniAc2R3qHbZBy@g3tOLDzVyZeUzB5A0ZwTpTE4T4G/VRCwczix2mdQUMBiUEpi5zZPzxrVY3jGWimZRDbCeS2NVqtaU7505NpZa7lsLqMnAUn13AdIhyN3cVscB6goJWB86dweVl42gb22t5mMupxVyZV5aSY3nS/S8ssA0U0IK130ELkagzgQZR4D/KoiGjQncV3BqCiPonoURVHbhXaG/LE9QrsjCCGzGBCL08jC03aneK3QeDTzzwxs4lU9oYPzNwUgVYdWhkyKLInNxk/dMbDMwjZrvtkYl07xNg0P4/L4tVl0VB/yoHazNs33yPkn9Iv6pWG956DSqevNY7hs5RcI4hhBlORlLFv7gp2OT516kvMmAzb9kWDZMDM7YP4nye4KnuX53r15UFvs@jFrSCx2/9hxUWl9BJlhMSNppJN6TplnKZNZmiWRI5EMZAePj3gLyYFoAjHRsuxX7tDb3ds/@Orhs@Mbh5FRyOj1YCDJq9vxU1VL1OqBIRrO1mKRPHiUPH7y4JFfEHOkcyEJDNqLyIm@LifzviiCnK9tvp61ZRhez91qjF/wDZDX8U0b61CjSDfw0FMfkC6tL1Qf0S6B64kbhWXUymbXoTSHlwyB3uNbvG6gGlMur2r17eqpE4ne5IQlFeGLiLaFlQBMp97WZhKZ/WbmMGPB9XYneDGPF66L6eV1Ud5M45k4uMl07J7NTwMSDiGPUH79ZEBESlrSD7qy9h1yrXt@ZpXBr9/jp@eEzwwJIZxLraN4CNSJf5MfSpH5iXvisLke9Aj7dlPyz2rhh875Z2MF583xc1ZiiiTObecJx8TdftPSVKPFBDEFpR3BSrB159f58BQJKjTqa88m0DN95g75Ob40afTQ8k1HLojfhxM@@2yxr04GEK5DnyOLBvBAcqsQGSgZDVDl@hNICXF83TSOBwRCejU8xE5kXBu0s7GpovWsadvugmyPKQmQaB/pep0FR9xhpulIOycqU5nNS2FtVfwYN@6Fyf5B5xxO5wiYNVOznbY1jUUvokqpDumje/TixXlUkZfxEp23KA4gbF8/eDFAP6@vlyTmWNRO/1TDZdKiWLwpJcDtOmB@YpB/iUixqPU8ie6CqqAufjwePQYjqBGxzsAcstjE4acqaYyssdOYk6BjaNQqP5jNYfE4dZHgQx4ao5gdMvH2O2Y6MxZLVoAJ0NVz2vh5Yw9ZTde0OpgpEYVt4uU@e6Bx4QkligS9WohSIrAVZCHoOABGvJJonMEhDvpLeHDMiM6mWuJNd53QOIeLNKFcs@o9FrqjaVFzlIvFkijQRalYZMB9N8WhlgSwN@Scr8sDdcUJCEAz6NBqUmQuyG9KvAilG@GIfCKOTgB0IqHDFP0TFRjAmh912OqN8Bfbd6Cu4CEwpecnjxoFJSmz4AiG7shu4zgcPw846LSJGxygmiYXgkbLvI/2MUbDs7Ua/IwHPPrpEVUY@ZpIjYTJcP3G0jlv6vparhcRRSlAyAw2AGKfSsMHh4fI@TOiS/yWC/uf/xzvRJVjmzu5dKN/Ho9mU2V46eUsy7KPNk9VdbNmZFOV@5t10xyfysxMZrYenlu9TvOgmzyVZZZmmWRyy8i9Phvqua0vatrraV2uFSqJs/qzM/bs2efvGu8UeXo@k09jLB9he4dvZR0yECnlWZHhb@lDlxUufdb00uUowD09xbtO5bycTNaidfgnr5fw8EC1qlbVdurv3im1PORpOjuN4BWC7PA@eVM/iUaaDEM5tm07yU6HXrsNP7fH6vwS3Ah/4vGYyoSDWuNubDDtkNt01@p2J/vmjLvbkQl@Ho1F3CffePHiBRpe0MPeHIn4HDrz0yg1zGyEGSnjz366cZW4fNbY/rNvDZLWBn4O8fPdqydoPtazH21sfPTgQSaTACpx87NvPPv67u5u5mEi@6yW3cmoqY3tP/2TjQ3D2DaSG3XP0@vR2tnZ57KRysjan/042nj27Gueh8WCT5rpYMR3AX466lRn7A08Zx2G/2R@0w6ZTTQ3O2@YEXkTAbaOzOivEWG8FlZISwo/G0yv7uT/6/cPX0fGkaqRfDGC7zjyOpIrRLgRDGBL@7bzSDWyjcFyV5FZslKpgDH/X/8dxK9@FeCgz2wbXtWsDys3i1TVCkV5G6nmwKAbBqT7f33zm7cM@9xnNXjkTN6Qd@rwbNGzLeHBV2oqmbwWXC/c0@8x5ox7Y8vFj80/DnyYWXag131Ui8fjdU2FR2tQpKSuG6c0YBNmLRpviQTOZcZdWMhtzifCBfxeRIingKmIr7hZOBCrcYcX18O9WPKUX/xDP0dSJLdx33pYrYIoTFfTW9U4PRunpRInf5LlC7Lr3pe3oMhS9HrM4AMCsyozlioYciKRuN8ArdJAmqpTQb9I9FSORiIv5yT1KRthcxsLO0UEKVlQB3@BcPv4/Pn/9uc/@PPv098P6Pcf8Ywwp213klsMr8Nm51X@sGpVro7ky1Oy3GepUqFUSDbY1Wlsq1atHzE99fHbaDYdPcZGQqdQp4o/whkJnmoVXz4aaKtGuEuVm@ZuwqcaWCjEPMrycExIJsZEItAEi6VUau0cZGzVz9H0xsNq96GQZCNflOtVI2scVuWULlOxFVlv02NuRORoB54N@KN/eHZw8Fi44HuDHLkPBV3ybASo3P4s1F4pUqsl61YdFFlW9YHc3yhtFEq5kgGFshpweRXoyHlYmmh5raAZID7e1TbYEef1Oov7z2n81ue5pjWEkQwu/lTVnUakyD/AU5VY5BKe@rut2jtgXZF0TdTT@LZar8YFRvDRGvfrcfXqqqZ9ES@Xxf92NTCW6eEmyEj9SlW3vwBYtZtQOVB6a40vtgFsfLu2XXH36Kc1kMRqNONGc@79@hfV2vYiCAHl/v04itr7AKe6CUyqxOObqrpRW5kHAFyPgRKwDQV4tX1VvaptX11tb8P/Nr2vxBdcr7Zv/NNn/qwIM/enanNaS1ZPk6eCbepg15JVdNGSp2CowhfCQTMkRUAxmUqRLbYVGTI9nwYTs0r6lpFOZqcf5fZBNarVVezBVNSansvWVS6pXmqspPKDxfVCTtFQFDXcTgP3AmrspRR5@f7L/wV/p@@//H1s96FaFqVIcgu7B0XeS4DXE4c9efIEf08cB/7h94Q/DrqgwxN0c/jL4SH8MIEzd8HqAEKByUYhJzfi@sxgkW05l0ex8Es3nmg0@o9eGsV8lPegcc/cSw8cf2nZ849@adUjRd4WsZ63PMbzJEWo3kNZQP2pqmp1e4BLpXBkWsVOwGeVqfp8V8VeqzmmuYYW75FVDvYrxSrqip4nRS4RSPM1/j1@g3@vx/h30sK/o9f4x07e4N/RGP/Ykyb@PfPw7@Q1/u028e9kgH8PXuPfkzH@Pe/inxSpgIq@uZPqp1op/Uw/A4PNUiOW6qV6ehv7DymLpWapGUsNXL0NJgv@UmCyUx2W6rKUk3J0HTzBMGapMZo68OnCXwegjODPxrn2Mz3VYpBKH9sbulCIvm9B/CmnUg06nvJLC5RpTddSWs6u4znsNbluFAtMw3LRGrWXp9E6HvBpFDOsObM2Tl@yiAeKeDmSPD1N8iEFZmTKeGT71VWjsf/0YaORRAF2@sQ9nP8fHg7C1rX/g0P3yaE7cOH/8PDwCbOq8ftx9T48lWp8W3x2ItXyzmlJxdruC5hIcnvntJpW0ZyLg7Aw0C3@gc8cInyrG6dSlIF@c1EmLap8cV6@KJMhsIKhUQ4CiGDcAI5loX2BS9lXwy7gOb8gR3yh8eLFaWDihuSLi1PsTUA3MfgHNTVs/W/wb/@/6//Jcxar1UEril1ebcfoUfBPUS6vLq/Eu6rEYsIS24Y/dAA7Rrm8qqKRAl2CqRZT6srVFXeDd0zZ5gCrmMZ2lSLPA0LtjwRpUrr8Fftv@8W0xXOKR4Gb8/n909NpKqWUm/7Rwzi3Zb6laValTBfJbDZrev1Pf0wHTO8oFCibKZf1LcYtRsYolzO@LV8olwu@ZTMWK958qqkdPQdqUSajKOUyWHZ8sCmwBmALANa3ZAGq5ZktqvflyOXBIR29DGIiG1EwR1wwxFJ0Qjte9hGVS/K9ezFxiejOrnLvnlFMvX0buAyH4KQvODUabXvUaKB7@u1buSHTfHsxC/ZU4e1bkGVRxR3FnuIdMZBQTNXZR0aV0iy6IyBEHryZnjTmWPRMzxyPR7E39jAh46ohT1boCodUyh2dRn/2vW996zRaqciqTK4ZHQFgKiy7vZ3LVKu5DJhzBaCUvHnJbzPpxou6crWZlDk1mLwZjQgvvZBXuGyMoj@0i2ynChXcw4ddXkWo2Fkmq8RAuiqgnl1F8I8768Uid2eZXKwQL4q/yobCqqA58D/s1abjma381v06o7/psgdFcvnSquhXlUurhIODV@WWuKAPtxla9@6li0DTQqp8KjUaD3dPdhuNiizL2B7CCx1JuEt4L9BwFK1RgWeL9Rrmr34ajZbK94k59EKWRaJlEU6NQivBCkUig2R3cA8x5F3SxZDBhmTQF1@SGEHaAMcINujz37PHu3v7JwljGxQh49HuXsI4fv4goqM1O7eTdxrtR/u7Dw@fQ4Rnj/d3j/c/Pvhs//kzcPfYxfzxJbB4z79h0xL7BXshvRq9MS3LtCaW1biYTC5es1e23bCBsP2Jbdtud8Q8q2FZ1hCC@U8Zfi3bM1@9MkdDetj7H33n/Y/@u/e/8733v/Od97/zg599@YPvwO8n8Pse/37v3xaz@P7Zl//sd9//9u@A43@E3x/B76c/@/I3v8l/ZP9j@P3nkNsfi18oHP9JAOtXfvbl93/8sy9/9Yfw@5fi98Obv1/76fLfD769@ofxvv@768N879/B7/c4LD/s936bu@H3Rvjf5uF@9Yfvf@Pf8/8/FX9o/J33v/HH@BKWf/rDP/3P77/1Hwyj8Kf/5v23v//@2996/@3vvv/2Pzbe/@a/0VPh1@@@/8Ef/NUf/t5f/eH/RP8/offv3eX//Q//6V/8r3/xv//FH4rfT@H378H007/4D8Cwf/sHP8L/7//B3/7Rj/D/f/5Xf/sHv/63v/KvyfBb3PB//8t/y99//Wv/6W/@xXf/6qff/Jtf/@nf/NYf/NX/8av/52/@p7/@73//r//Hb6Hjb/30r/7oV/7yW9/5y2//87/81pcr3t9Z@/7yDu5f/gO43B3Pu8C5S74@1OXLXwifvw815qkAnwB3/5P3v/nLwOC/wdj77/wEF8vCb8X/TwydwvyE2/4/YDBu5hl9UmCC36@//873kET/A5AI/gN6fTewLPhwy3fnFiDrv7gWKWKVFhvPglGIb0EPY6tYFA1o4L1NMX/25T//cZDELy9CXfCDFL@LkmrB77so497/6Jvvf/yP3//ot97/6FewNVMzxcRuQtXXD1lDE6hm7xAOA@buEg4Cfv45pD@N0wCrGkcb@1x4fv7559L0bRJXZ99/C66fkxN/GPcCPya8fD/hjutbw2G4MeUbN9H5bThpJEMck42TKrDl6ynZNJvGBUZTHL/DL7hDoOkWGaf4Jlf0nkr4mv/PjVOJxTGMGLmMz41kEPFEEtwoZSGZ@HTq04sUJ8aVlS3uQnNPlG6myDAH02l8Cj1SMEAKcfB6EGeVSiWOESscH7By1KoFRqjE4xXIN8bmcRKNAoKYPiAoELMSP2KNrcqUR4wjvKpPjriETkeybsjxQuUhJFiZPmQIC4ET2JcvK9VCZVpFcO84PeLT@APCCYFV4tPqO7BXCGYch6IevgNUCpV4vFrABDGTvHgSDV5IWcoc5T3O4qIM4EvjuvcZ@0jWCzKfB9lAgvHQ@I7PQ@/QzNwO@J/Gt0R26N830m@LCL5BSYlUGPffIVVxh2uPGADgqqqmaQx@ONu3w@6D95SDilOy8IlzCHHiCOKAwAHYEMsiTuUbJwukH6lsffATr0o8N5ubm1KkKqflQ5oXikOvfXRW4jeSvOVdoxKTc0UZnS1aL85zZ20@o2GHrYdb8Nbhf3@DlnHHWZnQ2ozikGCU8fTYR3H@u39/i30Euafv3E1iajztZnBIHjO6HY/LBqRadePSFyDdJGBfAvRW0qYVmo2KS4kEY1olgn7s8PBQoEYOX1SkOHC/kdbRjtMHk8kkAjE0LaElEuKr0ZccNGHQyFd8tU2kOQ1hMsPIlKF/U2boxMLdER36rej47t07KCxaylE6gB4lE6s6jEyBPMGBb1rt92f@bgMjU5R4d5rpOX5neIyuFFSYIrEY21IkvuiXI@E/sahRKETRpECZaLEtf5FPTpf8kcVIFRH1H97HK2QV33PvkO0dPnmy//RkWK8zyaK7Hq3GcOS2LM9bJ5hjGG/36UO@J8Ao5hCNSK2GKZ@UDBRL0n4pRULz4OHRwXGJcZqIEooFkJQyjRoLUhR1KTIcvtiOiIUQMl4@4srH@C7N8x8zimlMsFqWIi0LuyXAcPjPytITr/vAnUJfPiHLCT2HXTSFxl2Z9HW3VKq80zN5Cb5knzA8JovvqYXaiSvHte1tIppUvVRprByNUMA5qVoVK4qYLlWP908gwskh042UxqCnf5nJG5lsJmukc7ls3tAzuWImly2koa3JpbKGoRczmWKhmL@Sqp@zqYa4qmDuV/qW0x33NnEdj3yakkP02KylEvhnpNPwBogJPZuvb2z0L1VE8JTY4hIXZF2B9VJFCnwFHiZ9RWJfASd4IA1cZcXEEreDw7JYZ4SnV8T4YiNZz0LlVqRTYCQOThqGn/IQqg909kM/KbLxjW@MWbUKnWz14JEUASnVY/5aG9Vuaz2N@Kg9GVnk22WsbX9m45U0Wtv2hn1zBnUzpUmRq6urDkA6eMSMqkFWHqON76sWuTTBfDU1pf//@cWeiKpWpe1hFdhxOzkEownGzHbSBGMTjNntZBOMNhiL20kbjJNqWk9tJyfQSkjb/OQnhhtLK/LYmuJBc9xNrnpWv6PhpoKKTAkY8rY4SbEq4lVxd4Zrtiu4@xBX1ceUS6ldabstugVLamtNtz3TvPGsj6vv@@6oEgVlLOp72HixKO7lqtRYXRu6Q2gyjWw@XtNTIKHxpxcSRiKbaOPafTFfspNNlS5sp@1eaJ8/efzJeDw8smhV/06mWGpreKYD7r7eKZSy2XqtJsvxGsGu4016vE6qGxvAx5bZVuHbcZ2xpxqFOkRu26NKJRrdSet6KZ0qSFdBjiWgFWajKmG8OKKfQHpdCpYvOa4D1auUMBP2JWW11Ol0rrYu43OLZF6q3AZEuIqbieZlYC2roXAlNknE7bknuJgdaF0uxVRRSTayBblcK8/t@Zxcrl9J9wdW2zZxJf9p6vJGpFxKvgrCnKYw2JJAuRuBTs0bwdJ6BoMBfThVgPH4sVlVWplWA6lY34fGrlbf9g/UQoYzDNVIq2ld1dP4f4vBwP@7hzfg38A3xEob0gluKn0KwhGkv8Me4/ndY5eduC5d1fbAaq0IsdczaQne3sj1vL9HmAemc8a9Htr8JKfA6xMT72jwBva4tyLE8@EA9z5ao38wCPuDJiBI9ZQCPIDXqO@6ywLk2fNnK3L5JDg7EYjBD0@E4EcHH39yEvqe7O/ufSLl2IPDpw@vfbIiUJY93n90Eljz3NePmg1AfH3/8ePrVvGJoJ6A470bLJv3DbqEa3jvQS/pnjBmc3NjCo0v@PYy2wvWlPJ9hCXpxN9zZjIUBE2Ltfh2VOy20fEdQnvT80VJGjLHvWD5FGu7/b6J11R2NsCxZ@JeGgv1kT7dpopJX7ijfvvCblsb0hPctlPU8S4@REL6BIAMJi3aK2@PJTwMqo0XSOL8QrM/sdgEL2ld4QgfdELjyO72QLZfuH4AqWmaDH4f@kB8K/yM1zuMeRrkdsOnfzO4FJFQ7TTHZqRQvndPfzYCzq4WUqVS1zorVfenwFnsOXC6OUK5u5lkm1m5JT9iWiNiboGO17VrXn3IClB26cxWTkd9BRRMUKtYosBQxUL1t2aAinWaNDOuU37D3GHVi6aurCtoPPLxnQy0DuNOqwwNEWqJ5dJf/4ufICtvJUFqRXRZxkXFG7qkkTprFAvZQjFtFBKFYiGT1XPZbEI3EtBbyBchtZRe0HOFbFFPFDLFdAb0Q/DNFvNShK/YSm4RSPiWAKzTwlvktkkj1npVKcLnndibmKmwiBnYJ0y2II6M94Z7Y9q1uGVXZCPD9BSDzhBANFmLRR492ks9eiTLD9CCs@17KVluoyVbSKXyD2TZIp@9ArbpssvjFPAwDnnMLanUgz1ZnnAAeI6lLPfQsp/DsRRZttGyt/voEabTQYuB8SHYGffhlr5vyUMwBy3pNA3GyPLrAByE2@UJZQjTfbRgmujziPvsgZ8sf@zjk0oBhCMejkP4xM/r7q4sH3DL7i767FHGsxzVT9GyS48sj8AC1USWu2DojqCCynITjFhZZLkFptbMBDe8sw8PO3TGpizPOIGQRLI8pdBm60yWG747JvPJJ5@YvXHb6vJnNuLfFqAGPvZ0sv@o@fHHzW63OZrt7n98hD57e5@Yndlk1Ow2RbRmAx4X4oDP2WB2/QEcDxoNs7/U51Pwca75NGYNC3FrmK8BJ/F0MZFBYw989sBn2ZQdhwbPAII28XkwgO8Ds0k@/kM@9J02m3IZGRXVSrp4F@oM3YGbGJitkVtG@7SywVg0Fk3MarlUvUwebAAKZKp8RTfuxvBtYudduZzVppVUvTKt5A2@1qMTk0@nRtaWExuDHb2YLW2YO7qRiU9LuHfZ7URZVNV3WEy/t/WGxZ4qO0Y6U5JPd3ZUuabXdwy9UMrlv9iayLJSwvdOOl@CgKkodG3xpdTy9Z18NhQln4@bSaOUzyvlKyDHGBrTJkqVRix2YZlnioLoYhcMssDv@51RPu1yJzZNTCscLzZTytOKXubncLHUDVhtPPRx0hq7Iw6xC@CmO6kS3Sgs68WCDOknkzFFAclEQgS@8/VfL752cnZy8jnILOjciq7hM35NZVlYP/5kT4PeorDhYY3aI1Tf3ZG2h4JlwYefJeg7nYDCq30CLSJo@L4b7icZuX1tfwodduwD@B7@EVyaODhJO/lkAc4x9It5yrgdt0wnPTgti@FZlnabmZUqmMw2ixFWzFQuqC1uVKuVRmXALwWuBrE@ZXTQ4xzMgcdxDzYJU/RL3GMhPBqV1FW5WZlGpgCnUWGq/nLgtl8a8Va5jUdYPqg8wMjlBnybZati4dXIckQud3acCmMTxzM71jNrhFveDw43QTPAjRexDrOUTXZKFynvoYZ9pVZHzJlj9nQyiJlqtaksOoWsSJrY1/wsX9JOIJwEvyp3Kiz2hVJ@DdbRJou1tQfKTqbcjj1gDQVcUi87LzvMYLlMme6WiyEkqEREG7qgWKlUPwVlhgM@K5UAEVHGZwATUwKwdps8TGVoX5VblT6LqWzKFCJPptyt1DD2W3xtq7JcV9Xa27pUVdUXUhXqaXkWMSvepEnnHrNUUzdSufIU3PR8ptyDgjW/mJZHleFkZJX7YBXjJHzDk1kGcgLVAMybt7H3v/xNZVvNVrhbmUC97YP@0NAalWnZwZNUgCUq6Qp4xGuZVCJbgOY@m09Ag2xA@59LpBOZhJpHV2iNoSsJjjroAbF@TGZMTqSmKU1P6JaegNr/0m6/ZEriLAaqB5EMLGN3H@9lBhcoJORKssLXZErc2OozKAWXmdsqsSlIijJmDGjeY0M70UNQR5bZpxiKorL0Vqy/GcMwmyeT4X6tXirtT4dfA6@Y@nonF8@n4m8UpRzbUCqe9VqqlqUqShXK9XADeFYMITFvMqhBGY839bxRqtWamMN8KpFOpSF7duNtd1uuyvVEaiOnQwldMdJjGBcYXJeZayNztwYq0HjJOdOLRlnSaLUEpajHjOKqnTKKhOv0BEBpKIQdUpjFTmV/y18sGs0b0agSLeNg84YsxghBwvH70kHURu/pOzLoT3JJLhoYYC4oaVdXKqxCXUnY@WaZohS5lK4ur7ahh5mkZXOgGLINMqla9b4UKTEGetypODckucHYh67Gi29Xv@DfU1zlC3AlOgkN9EVaI2PZ2C1in@EO1h0WBcTM0aBmGOl6zchD@wYy0w9qGHoZh9IjuI5YqwLlvUvAbztexc0fn7LZzIyrPmXvMdaNb0qU6ch1su9WdrtHu2XftoejeaeSLMvlqBy5jEaiV/AnRe7TjhOD7zhhkdCeE75KtWUBfd5FSGKwvUt/MKeE93HEzBKXD7W68u6p3b8spFXexQeBdXUV2UxSiYiF@@VPXxpZKCPH9VfyQ1cHh0mg6cpmcSgyknw59L5hFNJPDg6dh6NHFuML@QuZhlyNsJSu4rr4ckm4ZvlCXrlYMGTjLBFh9yPlCDtTo3qJFvuz4XHxi/wXhS@ePD98fvhIipxuvN1wcZia@WRh75yvfg0CRtOZKGOnlci0kimLZVHVqqpvG3giT57hpfcdPaem3lY5@1bJI2eAz/tf/mFmul0AuwHaawmKMBs3qlV9y2BKZPj@y9/Hoxgu9z/bfcyinjljf/cnPzbyf/cn/4oWG0Wvyh6NieYjEBKNei4fubwcXl5ewcP9spF6hCOVyStg5uPvemS@n6CUNM2tfDxj3HfKSRFWz@tKxFMjYpYhn414b4WXkSqAlz8NQE5yDosgsn9kZw39/jYyhR5sQ2Lz2WbLKwJXFJ68fMsYWFrVdrdrG2RKJlnpncq236nb7B0Oo79TN9jLShWnfnXcvOQPHG9Vq1WEwqLVeHIryows@NWuyvU4o6Fn6Pd9YW05W6eLHH26wYpFB9wtb0tMVJxuedDH23Loz9ryPLD6NmvrlcdknEpJJtttOqNm22LZKpT/VhLQOVXe//JvGkbu7/7k19423jY@N6DnVizmdCPyc/3nP4cAa3bN@90uGlbH7e1oCLprbMUFzVoLeop4a3eH8fB@5w27a6gz2F0HuuZok85Rz6GiafCjmNoxCraFm2oTpDXTQSlKWZIC7ZK04lG3lSAYbAsPz4e6KV1KX0EvaExZBcSl9JU5KHAYQPPpthpefzIa0iL9GMXT6wl2D6JACl/BU642aDOwkLkqiKnk1s2oHGWPqEY6ERtYnodnZkErIn0FooiDzvBOYBP3rWNI2wEhr2EQwpM82jVIuw5p93mEBrnGKPc8QIJx7HgkBzRn6SugDBAVbNARmL0NAcogWL4CBIA8xARgu862WVphl3Y8Xp4fyHWFS5fxYDHT3zMrYTSE1sY92n7kMoYDJ9DY8Wod5AtRwqCehRx9IBwGn1qtgM6P0cmGShdtar8zKIBFB8jEKGvs3r05VpWK3VYY5Qjhn9lDHICicnCW4wrA/P7SR@2SnGB41FnZdw3YDigeJ3SB61R@xlk5FJXJaL2SJPi/M9MiR14rKvIoYwZEefFa0QKSQWQkOy/DFtuuMN3IKyxAvgW4twgpOl4r6ASeTj/SjM99zyvA8OcR/@BqkD4n4UE9wbfXN00zaPYmeGowHp3DhYHY7MwPx0EpdjD2YwexICt2n0J37BF0UGhq1z9pK5bWFYw2P5mM8KDFyEaG4argrIIfioWhGXxNPFNKpLNB52K0XChQb@g6dAgVHZiBC66BI0BGibN8ONoT5wJPmRdlQ5HDGHl0jg9yPmJMh2rR9XwUF@dKmyPoxfq0STCrq7HWoM2MIosRo9GZQ04ATqFIhHATtF2kcbNvDQClY8ui3S5eKZnsglY0adLBS09s4KveIxuaEsdLipsQkxf2mZ08wVNyVbeDm2L4NvYIKlJY/fi0rDjkqO@6Z6xvn1l8rDa2cAiAx0DfB6U1AZSd/4CwJRwWNtIJlgLvBA8Fvzx88txYSITibsRmys1vWt@INbBE31KbZI/wlsNz0wnRl563kujiejPPP0aEDsMAuxaIXEscIFCJ4t7l4GQMSRyIUqGzODQcrx/GoMPpHySCRtDFrXOGnVUJ2xgQmi1/Sz7WYsjtV6gBoLoHNQvPFBuPSniQBGAyasdaUPWEgHfYRyxtSBiQn/IiTmQBGFj0lUXo4AdRMR/euA0Fo/HtXyBXoHYO2uCHW5gF@2F8n7vRTOe9zdmbbQhw2OhQWhXGq4VvyYYsWDuQnynrG@CZAwyXYLIRk@MANi4rMgcdxL8enXO7RLKkxG5CSjCEIEgNUEhV8K9BZaHj4CXweGB6/HxKcfrYxcWFRsfgTUa2Znl4RLqHd7smh10bdGI3ObYGQ3EZlY2XEAq4c5PKb0bAG393pnTXbvHejH8lqeNVxCKKWLTjRbFxPMcTwLsDOj4Hz63xiKEe2XR7QCsm1n1w/jPqiUuf/0rIf2oheoVAGEMw08Qs0UoAsESzdZboXLTLwuOcKiQAh1K0fEc8enLkWwaeb7KHnSCEO6btDb692T@jaU2AJPOh03nSPId@yJlvFfahPYVIjnXBdkcjcxYjfwVDIwPHZqT2sBk0@@QDRmhm2CU/B9Ge1mb1hejTIDo0an6Xh43wbBzpcj1Qfigm@k@5/xT8p9x/Ok/UT7Y2rXOVDJ2uMDvI9Xikmh8Swcz8MFf8AMm5D0EGxZrpHASGnC24XcGvVaHYPr25Dcqx4jMG8MQQCG7FkrUvTmundcezLrbq8WQXmF0mQkCJA@hanWh60Q7MSP3@eX/oegtODp6kB62SwBudWj3BDZxXMI9BARFjcHrZePhZdyBm47lCIDIMEFAPA09UDXbHMVspB4ewkicwTk2e05gjVhPI1En7El7CDdQlTnpO2DCgeggQugdZAjTBh/k1h1@I4UuHFyO899sPq9IZ/gM8hCdajwIlr1UVLmvKVEghrFTVRxPIjupq5XpWfH8oito1r1A2r0T5h9Hf@GD0O1AvlmNPDMsbjLIUriq4qgxUCFFdiKqsWgmVK2CQ3DL71gharn2un4rWGpLZSvrdDJ4OZsG7wFs@Y6HCbym8fGjDmezIpYAVZpUKZHFW4dWS1wufpJzgQTRPRJv5jCDicwECMFJLo1ki2jQcbVqpcMHBpiuiXYSQnBKSUx6Fh56uQLIuokHvKbgeGounDtoprmGTAZ7Om1FQg4Yyw6s@cVr6FR4QhrOUIs25zCEuEDyEKjbyWau@NPVaCOmQ0LoGABnxBoA2v1urJF0XeLoa2AIZxUnpyyhuE2zAZQUwGIngMj9EMxYwGfWBQeGX49QOQN2V4zVJ1mlcF/9S/CcnfEf/p990TC2G1BcdU4lrf/8gjnWkbKiChrQPPZVBgYw9mefiUvQFnSOC11D2XNDqmhcuiy1RtsE96d@nnmz23WZyYOJSELxxJ7hlXfH7Dzgnwu4P3bE5djOZEu802cR2y9LnfQa767h4UHfo8FzQ9dqu5TnRMRRqy@06tmcl8F53rrJbtDCBn@MthfVkYXQ9SRJjkLwbi6A5X6Gq22jgHYCNRgzXpSmlYPkrLVND9oxGJez/gikUH8STAHo4jLnNV1ZrrNwOE895FtFO7NZZ7HAoPKOQyC4DGdYC/R98e6DBMM@d9xzpxFlUpZvjGJ3g33MHbhe0vomnSRj7GviDOWxEyBwOCZcEM7FLWwqd9k21JNZKmIqI@ukHR2WfGjFTCeIbiwAWiJFgo@s0RsqOliTXWJkcj@and/zh@B6H8T1ejy/1wq/jzLvmFe75YUmnY3MIEHCORvp2NDDrILfaN9BZQCVwRr2KR7gzim1aatVGTHch6K4IrnWAPxKBzQNbgPhnq@i/vgD96Pt3LT4TL0Y9noG8GeAKwBid4@/5k5sxCH6gKFJkSXIBaz@8Y1oQFq@1eYQqBKixJLgcPCwTKuYQut1ecIS7D/gWnscVUzf4npZRVbjnEpxG5wl2ZqwuooeNttU3Z1Y7JkImQnD9HB9Bh43k1d0yjoKOhJ7L@3oxaLuUwBeacSQ6D1RawTJm4lxRVrMVD2IH3EMj5YThwWr6of8N0YxDfBU@Wg39gGgUD25zzm0c/hzOhjN@HnOfX4kh5Chvf3hJ4rb62wkCdBDH0STmySrrxOdRLMjSHVqEIKy2mGU8LtWHiGe63CzDDyPR7TmFwg1FqvilLC3eLbC8xO11JR7iCp8n@bzR3VjyNqa7M8@FWI0Dm4uwvQ9rQm5AxvUYrVYsDJG7rC0x17khE9CNxumcFa1KY4lADWKSpBvb1N0m/UKRsGd8AF8ccPoMvgiwa40bnKH8vOGYlrgXhZHPwByGtBbhAko6QAlRkZNcoBEKJflmCH55FaTZWplm60aarYU0gxqwmGQokNRaSFKUAhbPuiLoW53xCumMXth3hs86sQ2P45ojHK24jNrRkp1g0fNoCQRy1IqW9mMglKPtaOkhGbxo6ZgMZ9HSp2CY163o22jJrxYYYARWMtxHdyHC0d6KlvZiypU0Ns8sz09Xi5aCMoUwO9xKFAFSYL5Ba8QpNscV2RyPLGjYSKlMMOQYL4HdJxqHSdAvBf/8thC6dQA9cYxziwKzONMXGo1Qi8HTgWbDP9V6SU0uidZ8//ARrWcKgmAycejjheMQeFDDI9FFYcQRQ1@a0YAvIIhys7QcIxZqye6IjkgdOJQKeTF9op5G@kA7Rv41CFyfJ0JXxIj4fnktguAFeDc8MfIqPG@g4ydHGOGcrLIELSTqy@iaTGFZL@IiSj9cQjTWvRgIbxb2g/BSIrAhmQ46HE3OYWJDd7jIJOSLi@DtcBwalOOVErn3WjSSCqJmrvAmZ5EzFAzhyq@sy04oHqK2IILQs5aq81oWtAski9FrLutCmiqvfIBCSOZADbdaZ3T9zkNhpHBc3CSorVjVDPlxeZIkuRbFJETW8HygiTnmqQed1308NejDuq9@zCmOtcQQQChmkAqXr@4H6O8u1999hdonwrUElinWy5vSm@r12lb2Gub9ebI3CxA9E@yhslQ5ClKYkxx6ByHNfB2v3VDxcckHV/J5ogH0a9q@T7agT3AL3a73LTgs1BJG54uOZwY4nhmrCXVTI@mfa77SomFKAg7PeIDpPGvrceUZX1bE6EPj22b/gwt4tFjA4cJDeJSB0TWS81o@mji0ymVet0FscxcUqXqJcUFO06VBMc8dQdzT1G0wbQsOh42jh4dPH38dGt18Pq@INno2xw9rLY61Bu04h0yLo4P2YEm3xUjgjRo42Y3D8XSL98apI9@QJVxYgzJgQio@@4k6rghZFpLn1@ouxONhQxQVsM7m1cBckEqo6pjYZNuCrmMgiDWObZkCiK/eAr0T1FtT6O6IRgNvbm40qPlqNHDxUqMhWjEsGn9GXPl5ZCM58UZ0cyS/@ORCkmhjP3t4yF58snvCTj7ZZ4@e733Kvn74nL3YfXqCG7SfPX/w@GCPwW//6fE@kxaWR@IlUdihBLo@tFoW3uWHh6tlGEHec4czLndiewp3PzYH7BO3ZeE01bZnDu73uEVzrHGVx9qH7ugMxzBtughsYI9xvQXdYgXdWFRu2rTJDtfyMwjbhD7tAPu8A7dtd2wIK2Hfd2hbnr/Xi/VtKEGQt/6e2QRXkvDCKlo6RFfL4QqsC4huQnicuwEwJl9/RZdj2x6PYLU1JggXPB9MwZP9oyfHDI8A2Dt8@vDg5ODw6TF7dHgE1mdfP3j6MdDz4Pjk6ODBc/SigE8OHx48OtjbJQeOQEpjuAn/1cQbr0VBw@BEldYZznzTHeiBbXHUGzV4dmHSdkOPRScOSh/b7NtvrHa0LE08VF9wiyNNFbDY5u7Rx59Bm8@s1zjD6U8F0/oD@blHF6dtptg2pQaVpQr1rSyqKzR7qq7QfMRgxvAeBatM@@1jZE4wHzgt4mnbFpP3cI0Kjn3zbflUl33QkNAGwEZQ/oKVCqP7T6LRxDaBrEJqrb6LByvy1PgiQmHBqPf9pSZliSgm1sogUNyvcODgeJBeDhyA78HBEMmORzwASwcOPADLcAdURQ9w7QjLihCT8eEExTPLcYdXg@EjmhZm@cDhgUm92ILAiZcbFanJgvuj8JCCPt1yw0d56PY902vZNkXxKDzeANPv84ph8bvHQCbyqURa2wYhZRA2HZxqEMve@CWd6AvcgOuEzM7YY7GKorETXBxkOTa/X6jbNx2@BGq@dId4jxXwGJqKWGZrB/fy0A6QoUsMiHeCLeIRxHsotELrrvEg5oMbKZpijSTdjecvQbsNgQc3EPhFwAAgdaGn06KWinaVIhi3I1g55rnAkThu@y4cHti5PWlZCxHEqq3YK/vNG0UQObHQT/LXKRJ2UERvrBGolTSV2XFHUMdJrNJNJigFWz13OLZ5GcYWc0AzTtTMQWhs2CC1l5XqQmpIh@spOq4TSrQJXLwi1SYw5V1SJY7nc@eB@JpfawmcD40wX3eH6JhNvAN8PneWwEmkCwuHX0ARprlyHPycjQkTrn9Kc9nxjuHNeIVK9eGDU/XdywRej8fFAr@R0l90iD9gTEwLqgfN89GCxRHqXaKm@dcaeZMmxhZr8IS0xFruA4N@YM@Gft39Rjnw48uNb7rjHpnr7uT49m2Fx1JRMolLSr1ebC7dEqzmJ5mgOHUmloCEZCcgC7I@5rskCGYgr@/jvhgshTJQxEE5gv32a5cGCRHi56456YBkEXc3iuIO4CusSisq5lfZ4s6WcHkkv4g9qMSrSnK@oISFyBnzRXTCh6wrSmhZCrVXN8A9XA8O5PfdwRXWYsebhw@C9nAttA/CTY2vhsWbpRCsu4N9twYsb9x@IbCQ98RqwLyRvAkt4PSAORObkWA17foUX94oO6p7AAbbXhxBCYCGUps4NEXtH2Mc4xGUMJi5QnR88nD/6IjJvH8CcUHuYZehLcQgwt5gz@arbW2HhJ0WKE1BZzlQnnyXhRVt/rOuMi8l3gpRIXSQhKBHICzmlzZ37CmXeqJlIRWCVt@TQPQpt4jdpS@DvJoA/P8U97RbbeRK/qafQrRJcEO7bZNACMYkBkziWT5yMSTDMcTT2G3jO8b2uA3YE9hzd3/sC@z@30fYV7nvcH/tU9ytD0mtbhvInOw5k3OCu1tSqVQqSaVSVekB9oCAbNRpRgOtmc1M8eLTCU0jcEk3l2Vj04afLKx57cYbEYcTE5BpE@S30bNkdv99Yfl4Q9XDAhYGyMEGN0GShvUG9glVqHgAGT0v3oNPdIvqUjSyZwE7pWiHhl@5uIT94wxFjMRCOMvCxrQuhWOJGsvHC0rMIYNEXAZ8tPSUiWzRDAlqiqcvm2aHOtGil44vQSBk4h15702ugOIXDwV9a3s6WieLWiA3x9oCYVNTWF6gdlbCLjye6QXaQq8lp4dkVTDbPllV5v@nKl4lYjUpms9sjEoEyGurq6@eg51shSqe@VHYvIYk58/R9QD29xHIcBKSeh84t3LoqvSIAZ4gHZvWqwGTKAiizow1JdZ2WoxM/AAX1gsBMhg@HK8dTNbqiHECt9nQeUUyoVOWqTYYQ1g3lEfNFPUfnq4OJ@Rn65v/4/XxYMNMaDr4gFb5B/1hGEReeUYUFeMT@q/GvwXDYY@ysT/TNUJJkxvTk8525G3HBq/cKkyk8zazJS3pncRmt67SNVAlpF708KZR1O4Vkuq9TL5gNnWvsl8WSxTWrxXTRdpD2zHmnvlO7ykEaA4mvQQuH@TD9yLcgP@Ag6tAApnImy9NtHGexY0oAlJzja50kWahcm7NJ3u/FTb8Hob0cO0XobDdl1CQtLDloz1nlmY9V4iVB@TCQS8NpVw749lUFL6hQhchxUFwb@J3Y8FCTw1lKfnE/fB@Nr@eW3trUet67si9rr29cJcaRVvA4uv3rsOb4V3z13b/6rYlumLw18txY/L7b0KsvhavoK6VlxzSNb9WzFI8zDfwd128zRHnSgTfUXjac1sIj@@kE2JRRPvwwrzg@9ho07yBHhIJLhVL14oL0cVuVLyurV0Ue8Vc4brWuyigk99ouThazi@n8cNLWEVhjuGT@droAtdUU@sa9G4FXlVKV8pJ1xBBriHw5cAfdvr7pcMPMW0cCgCoApO23qRQ51tG59CaDX1PvF5wl5ZqMlcgx1ooIFlz5BWUR5920iejOqbZAcygV1yQZsMx/Z041lzOuxmM@pSiQvcha4n7zr01p9yYcqRRgCy1jgrwR5erh@MoTxoPhvjrhK2oM3kW1/LoO@kYIGpYkqZD@9y20acQEZW@XLULK/QCv3GFSOC1uvdUTGxu0iW7wGqhR1o8NOXwh@QwkbvARzwAgZ8BnTZgFSS5h@T2YUHz8T2PD/yFdFQj8pMhA3mLJEVMQfNv8Y38m6j8JhCACT/HMpcnVZxS8gJBkn0HSbmAocfiG388ZkC3Su6UOWwswub6ihFwshQnGmG1kkzwfe4Oycm0gn@yBZk8vU01Q@d3ODuRhM6p5VuItKQupaQt/OlGxdJGsYwqpjIbpJh7lhqo6YLt0UEAw2oidoJuF5BmWsxF5MBH8u@V9S/r@sMa1nmhkef0zFR6JpbucTojFeXyYIGPMm2YmezUtyjfg7CjbO5UXUVBwosHPd3wQCSJ8haeyht6o369E2Xe0l3JXKkTNmMJGSPl64ze55T5WBnN4Dq9xumSv1dkz2ssY3nfx@vHX0t2UEDGs9LWJMGlXq/TfceLlk5BNrOBmkJwcexvYjselNIHU04nIMGhnp@G7VYxgrKcVzMOjRl7a/O97Ukh4106iQZ7MU4NrBljxKAS1blMhBuTwyLUQ8nzBgiCiYwm1MjdUoUnsvDEAIu55lW17AU5NcChackhXkS/yHv8owZ7HDmVLzU7cY4xH3Pj2bs5TiCadOft2WSKzyboLsIfZaOeWEWiuidJiLMniUNDC6zrDNgHu4Vq8Hk9T5gThZoppuiuUySlowx5xb6PdSEmPlj/zC5ZH3yQsQfdYCxKuM3wyQvLijm4j4JwFGJsJ4pFE94MBl08dSSB745cqGWgkJVVPG6JIBoru2dV0LKH87v4JB3SoZAnjhDyHRqIRAnhTbuNzmToAdu/w6kVNS6dkWeVehNWaMCYebXCbuaBuAn51BR2@20TCe45Hj1I6XDgNwLPAhktBOnH4qa2OvLGRNKno98IRg@DJW3Dsv5y02n8uvMBz3Pf5HOv8gbJbuVxcM579TpysAIiqYSVHIixq/nXlmWcDTf4bDiDAF2xjwv9Z@DN4Dbo9QKrBCsGZQxBaA2D4W3Q9CzrONCHwAgXWRlPJtEPu38zbLByB4QuH5gRvYRDl4/DgMPwF9dnPi5u0FmZa@GhVXTaDF1922kiAZXHSauPp8N0YIFhApgeWOg6GAFRlhwRR4nOniUuJLtcoyIKqIFxToyzCU2GXn/UaUDPkCbL6gIoPgaJKus1E5hAfY2uj87B3iwE0D0mooBCQB0lPYWDJQ/N/xAOQjZMnbH7qmeyMPv1aazAcA@GHZh9IwJTr1AxA3fo4JOPlaqoHu2dfCkdlwU8fzo@@lzZLe@K7TM648aDcophKz4e7cPsok/T@dT8CD7YpSqUtCnBKh2eifLPn47L1ao4OhaVg0/7FYAG4I9LhyeVctUVlcOd/dNdOn0HCOLw6ETsVw4qJ5Dt5MilWlUxKyonjvbEQfl45yO8lrYr@5WTM6pxr3JyiJXhqX5JfCodn1R2TvdLx@LT6fGno2pZYMOs3Up1Z79UOSjvelA/1CnKn8uHJ6L6sbS/n2jo0ZfD8rEgIwGjldtlwLK0DVtYrInauVs5Lu@cYIOipx0gHiC474rqp/JOBR/KP5ehOaXjM1cCrZb/cgqZIFHslg5KH6BxVvoZqkC/7JwelzH@EVKierpdPamcnJ6UxYejo12idbV8/LmyU64WhLV/VCWCnVbLrsBr56hqgAHUgnR43j6tVohulcMTWDNOP6G9gwOd/AUIA1iWoOguERjNILC1QKSj4zOEinSgDnDFl49l@H6MNCVqlZAKaFGxc2JmgwqBiCdmM8Vh@cN@5UP5cKeMyUcI5kulWnagwypVzFBBg4wzYB2o9JRajf0EePEjMKulONel7hSVPVHa/VxBzGVu4IBqRXILkW3no6S5h9FwDSVKp486A//aVKy0pj/dBhhcclojM1tHoyMm7RztlmFFlsGq7CjhFFad9UQoJTMNVhqdCK@xkDXN4PKmXe/0Wn30MdXFWPFxHbZdvL/FwWsszq0nrsmQ@hUqkErV659LddjoVut1x/2ekjE0nish1eBP5XJkGzEWP@68UfGzscF034wRauulPOgkQz08gMCcTP2XbPrmXweOyGabgSyGzvsIWKmOQj42ucKjFJgaydkR79qIqiTNBL13JDtQwbQC7zXqqCdFy0jK1A/hT@8@euHFwfgAszOru7JZ3MQSGp3fA1UNV0IhEeiPjEjQaVGVXhgEv7bTObM63PN77X6/mXYcVYbyjmAf2E47zxS/DNqJ4plkeUKWjp1lzPxQ7btJhNHnz5JkQvaLN6SWpfFPfUQ/jsKGYz6g1pSqImW1VFqmX3JxtEhyhQxtge4V1Mko8x2Ufq58wd1cbuV1IfH9o/7OYwvtBTEILSx4NSp3QT8fLzgDDDCKxQEk6cgIGdmsUUbZm@jMd5DxCjPddZpo@QNr9VVA6zqQBATZG79r1omr8bAzNrGHefjDcelg@3RvD6ZOxPb1@uqbtYKlw2797PLvGdZDkWIp6tgA1nGQ0yjJGCU7IPjQSDFiaUfsTwyczWJGjKeuOo0@YpwHbbcRt2TCiQybG@LFMz000bMDpIMtKADHvKX4debIlAyQjjXVwdZc@2MS8X2QlYgHpDFLd0K9NsY/CFsPfzXEdYMkA0kWo9i5wLmwu6B5z95TpqK0uaHAPZjFsxUfcxg3TQNSdZH9LHrX0pvkbaMXQzZlxPFK3U4lAYn5JBZC2VX0eGR/ojgjUgFM0cPgy8@S3@DxTAa4o3B3fjgqjapAxj1dEvXUkTJaNromIV9sFaGLXr7UNW0K1PI7Eikae1KdrAODGKOBUMGbRNDGNw64oOOIJKskC9j3i474xpyKwTsQTkFyrHwHzp3VHAmloOKHyHcVlUIwLB3khKl2p@uwVJYzHcdCkTNGph@iB8H/E2kyA/4m7DgBekQtIwjgd1GSoDKtYPtKROncqYMG43Qjoqb56SwC82B2zJVumDy9GbN/DZBA9s5EfTijsIet9AwCIJOjYsMcv9ok7cqHrdN725HF8Zyk17gepIVcK9RSMQU3s3bhktjlqrMVfHGEw7omo8J9KCre88btkkY9bJkSW3nxIrQZnKPif2SXSAGiBzxx6RVbrSY5KydHmZoHZKglY8Fp6ohJIJY@PHpqtySMEJmxuV@efClCAegtxGe6nXTRR1@weW484iKtxOKEouBhPHDcJuPiI0PWXZIhZjdAOC@apAzBu0BGd7hAdBk6heqLoIn0CzIUwUoiq8MoziBOt44HpKVl9U5jT5pJ5FCN/WmPA9EHrNVSOTwO8CExNN3lPXHgTwDl7vc1m1ksu1Ttu2i7iJWxWkKWx3tPGv3@EERHH9sNOLqdieOJL1LpEPTCm6GMXwjrWWcoNRJK6IdqUGzi3TstMxwDnlALOyP0Vmh6xB/UpOsALUQ5PMk4sybSwLyKR7eU0rEzXs6L9GaUsgk0obCkRMRNsSbu7zkXE1SGDA2Igp1Qby7IZpPqwXMHPfzu@sNfce1HEajXDJo6MqkBknSB3EmVHsV4bIy46YN@SBoN6ArUgGhK5FmRpg1VYY1@I9lJ2jXZUXRMjF1KLfnj9WgmVdZSUFHEuLJ2YL61DHQmUmlFhgbVwULzK6uEyqwN18OjmzGKFho/thb2eU9PKRssRBRfKNERn3je1E9n@CSV/MUXIY4e@IJn3FIERYRRZsVz1el5jvBDm4IvnWDYNHWiIMk0/QGq32jr0@8RLyrVoQz71/BHYTCBHUAj2xlnCUY9/VP/qlff6Xf9dqff8WGfhmHcxzzj4eOEHrHD2sP@XUhX@lBC08jUnETPHF@Gw7Dhuz6XLBihucJRMEibZgqj4aR0xWEiSHOORoDRBZLE34NkjDRd5vVqVMiK@5@SPV7eKTxa9lV@VmE@0UcAcoLbSlhQsA/piByTDOfTwlSGy6cyGDheiozwnUcs9mIYvwUS0TFMDGOFzJRZgtkI3Jk9inGtOXabFINwiIGWgt0Ar5wJ0/TZ9fGqXphF3qGlwIbIr@eMonyKMsY4hPgweZzcK2/@ZOwBgR9AP/9qFrfMYgSa4loq2lLI@xUZZRRwIfPADs3RNBPDLNZpwyrUjQGtj5NQ48mTx6hBlj8gFMkwe1NciSMyDRsfvCUuXYcppz5xcFFZFIsOxe1AEaQ0SuceZ9jgOftZGvx4iMuaM5yYdiTktIH0Y6RqAJXwVtKEea2JMsdUfn7ErKx8b68lCFicZXJm3L6btpXkQh4oHV5f8VirP4TJ2E5QT5p6LIaj/mDxO6n36NwxMzLbLFo3HOdZQ2BmtiIslktNIm1xgo@TgpXEJ8E0cYqRpRnwEG5f6VmzeZKI42Idx1uxPnmGDo/RLLKb0ouK7u8mj31cFG/RolctNHpIEe4YpLSgv9fq0PD64zOIhMnbqzrNGHWcMuoTfjRAJcikqfT9FCLuk7gn6NEEymG9TaCd2T@PEjVpJKdCnqqkWJBLpCcGbkenTZiXBi00vsAwcSzh6klKC5xjd0JHefnMJQYZxgQGiFJxkIn0UKzBjTorwUd0O0ArXUdroTzORPC0ZVo46KD/mmAUlV8qd6TFQ32SyV8UGNJYQ4JdBeV6CpLyN4fXWn1MUKZIAUN8Bil0i6bmpqvvb9WPtgXyAQQuTcnS0jfnYmMcsQzYwB8zqT5GGTiqSpaMjaj4QKjT1ABjAXYp7W7A21WU/jpD5ni0bpDDCDYQ/DmNP8uyBIbzXstpamORcXOCWRxJbh5tjshscZGIofgdyS@HIou6tHEFAAFjDOWLeYCAYU0JezwUoNA7JufFEJV9BAWLeRyW8JGiokZ2njPSkagyw@tVI0duVo63JozMTCAgWMzOEyECMsvsLBEUWOhm4mLkeDO7PVEOEIgV7zPFoStkr8RpqHuOCUg3E@ecaEap5YWbkxxMia9XnVii5m9KfZszUnPJVKCPxrCWySdT13Ox1Fi1KyvxorGSQA/HrDWWCKRwTIT1rPBj/8g1xQx5rm1CjU1GTMqQ9tl4czTsMmHf5v01FJvklK1kDAXP9AxX2686X7ESC8r@dAB2sUhHBhi7/YdbqyxTFSbyrgCKS6ecXdK8ISSJ1calHpuFO10VaU8HKFB72n5LfD7Z24uFfb2cKEOj62C4msvlkIkvzeD3yrYaVUmdfjaeO9u66Xazg7ufhp8vszT3BwFdCbChdtABdAkMitDrD9t8MwTiAFkxd0Y6suJe/6bVMq9gwBNK7DzoNs4poyEIWoA62ujl8wkpgAikXGB/wQZi@34RevTd@SxoSijqGApKo0nwra1Oz4A8@KGF9tn6pIqA4cSsrJlg3XKKW99wBcGbTaizKHyx8y0yT7Y/Bt1u3xVf8FJgjBQw95AssLdnFshxFjxhJO/em5Di0boiuO10Db9izGLyOoJTC5O6Z0LFhcfY@MdBuzwepO3aVxuWFWjyMjZzGeNTu8Ju244MFv8dYJkPAe3vyn3tD9INolMyMyz1cgRHT4DRq7w7c@8Ty@KQTkzS7PncSNTZ6HoUrAGa7pAsoGLZU/dSSx7Jrolrn4/zLaRhjmFInDDmyveVQFezP29avB21Wt83K9I1ANyxf2hG5JtQfmxCpDMAGoFy@AE9MYr2v2RgWO8lAoqwgIOXdUzPO1igjgUs60Wj@NtdulQqiYXB8rIolbbhIZMRpe2S2MUP29tiF9638f1lcWV1tcBz7q7zDT5uq48PYhtgkIZzuXE13IVXSCui3xhaa2MXL2SLC25hoV7c3CqE2VppG9364ekf//Yf//j3/8yW5Mt/48s2vdS@6kye52UXGt8WXj4U8L22e7G4cFlbGFwstgvIZf@kqOH9yijjR@aj3vDSSvEqYHwlO1K1z6boM7KoULf6XfvDX2F22RCpRphNya8h3xxFc2yqERjfA/SjvIQtvLp0ILmVByRSAHSC6njonUaABniw3gAlARe0A@XyfLaiFPcYDkZn0KcqKRmJh2TW2wB9WqJICuiLCytWptMLgx5qwG9J5uXmWZYPv51RXfJv9utB2N7uj8XSeVos5cSSK5Zsm37ya2/hq7OQ7aB3LmeD7YBtu5ASHS2gmaEIOyTo0f6B7tpJkNuyFujKHoSkwlRQZvaCc/Xuj5xl@MK1sG3N4aWZglUkdMiERVLfFnoP0C3fIMeDHXO1IUGhLncxVJlxoqL7F0UgP2RDgKjmaybIRh@qxJM@8kjGp6z6IvvaotuECDCS9fjDHo17/ABr0UJP2jzH9lJ4zRGZz/NXXBsL7AxNaGMK1x8hQAcqvJ3MkSfhYmrRYitvo5XUTPbCNtsnmY9tHSbBSNmmc6F/FQYTsDW3SbiFnvRrkYbcfLwi7I4@XjGqspO238IyilzfdEedgXRXoNpxQH3TtT3wSMIeJUAMh2P2b0yPMFIUqEhRiW7hy7ImotnHpvNI6EnXdOhgx@OTI4MI2a9pGNv3ibHtZMlLRLED8wAhpU35Wn6nG8qoK0MidtsfXuLtgH6LLlQb8bkZ6fPwmtQExv2WRtojyGRyHo1naEpqMPTb174rUof9k6E/qcCyBZLPqOE50EIMwYRI4OCTVc9qnkKYWyS7hCiim0KWQ3h5QXcir0fjvrW1zwl2qRoKMuwKDoIYOxElg/tYXyXoGHH1H@gEE@WpyVufRsoplmZetDSSkGzTbYaG2dTQsVQN5tjRA8e2GFU9MhUvyEI3uNBe08EvzORdjBEg67alF6B0RVh7i/Xj6tQOen5scRp0LeXony0IXhdxPNNVlGyNZKmbT/PRjXeIFciRX@NRIHhtUuGMrLl0eu48lNe5pcx1hIJ8a1v8rC86@gI6usCMPEPEaa/Dk2VihYruwPBEhSz/AUKr67cBv8mdP0FWPE@l381nndrX897FUvq8d3/@u0OYyClZrbIZkZKH2WrGkmMFVsasG3tVVmmhCjV43otnOO8J9mExSACIZNO1r9mL@ywgdJ7CO@XPU0yQWJchJtmn68si@OwUmqk4FtmUNecsOarz0@/yjoC1lX6xD/mDw7@AhdpUkpoe9jnDFoAiP93fbtjlJMyur@Rer@Rfw06oHYwzw@AG19tMeHMZjEGUCHE7C0vP@e8xbogR4mEc@gX4OIZ28rUm7HsSSiclOYXKYU71WJqtoIzHPAH5gcoULhVdXBydx8fDR9zwuwJYTuWlWFBsOmhwXxrXz7B/jfX4Ic5rSe8Q5ki0MmAbEVKhZhCyunzlMQ511HBZJD8nT@xg7FYCAt2bTRmrRa/fy0hhzfEWCyhEo9dMdz23nkuO0akhGhuhC1KYWpwX@a13b/7@X0e/pUaprZXslyH8jlK/pdbWU/wID/D2Sr3dprZSm5ht7SE1ycIeGB7f/P1/oPzWTwAHUyab8GdrVcFam6S2MkUqcp/aWoOH/MoK1Pu/f/sbtGGBd2x4F@tC3RWEWEFRZMfvEe9CuqhgK3lbuhhNK@SYhTDYwhD25vCChlHjlfUcqelS0qriNpCRr5Q9ilziyTBrRKZCrMlQ9hQgGXGBIlaQYZDKhKIlDNsNZbaBzBuhKX554a2FsAP4RZpz6Cq16caLEE2GFnhbBB2Y5hphP88PW7l3tjbv2LCVTUlBiZC4tZNz7fqrwv8B)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/h0tk6)

What is not mentioned in various online compilations of CSS hacks is that many hacks for IE⩾7 work only in standards mode.
Another caveat is that many property hacks work only for some properties and don't work for others.
For example, hack #25 for IE8/9 on [this page](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt), `p{color:red \ ;}`,
works only in standards mode and doesn't work for `p:after{content:"x" \ ;}`.

I could not find any hacks in quirks mode to separate IE7 and IE8, so I switched to standards mode with

```html
<meta http-equiV=x-UA-Compatible content=IE=9>
```

(`V` is capitalized for Grass, `x` is lowercased for Puzzlang).
`<!doctype html>` can't be used because it works only at the start of the file, see also
["Activating Browser Modes with Doctype"](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/).
The `<meta>` tag needs to fit entirely within first 4K bytes, so I placed it on line 19.

In standards mode IE8 understands `+` combinator and `:after`, so now it should be separated from Navigator 9 (#266) instead.
I could not find any property or selector hacks to separate
them [here](http://browserhacks.com/#ie) and [here](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt), using media query hack instead:

```css
@media \0 all\a{:after{content:"314"}}
```

Any alphanumeric except `0` will work instead of `a`, but `1..9` break Retina ("Reference to undefined group") and `1..7` break
CoffeeScript ("octal escape sequences are not allowed").

Answer (score 3):

## 315. HTML+JavaScript (IE9), 14516 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=x-UA-Compatible content=IE=99>ss<!--
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,+i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media \0 all\a{:after{content:"314"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:>Ex Cr Uitharbody$/ $5"c"F ._#a*ee gi[s]p 8ogr34*61  prstd6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\/a4on;z op>s'0}e}equ7+?4[0]tfc;[ ].c5:2>
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39cyPbdRj4s9r5Iy4bfAOAQDfQjW@AAIfD4bxHvZnhiOS8eRKIh2kADaCHjW4MGiCB4XBKUna1VuzNOorskuXET1birLxOVbypzVre2EmV/WvKlZ/8B4w/trZcW9Z/oD3n3NuNBgmAHDmu2traJtF9P88999xzzz33u2V4/Z//PIIPe@bas57tjtnY9MasM7LOzZHKHszYfcPycnpGkjDU7qg3GZjO2CtLEaYx5o2N0ZjZhtObGD2TRcBVZ3N717LH5ijJPNNkLdN2L8A/w5hjXrADp211ABIbu2emY70xR@CXZeyhab8dvB2ztjsYGE7HY8OR5YzJN8fYMwMs3Un7jBktbzwy2mPLdcArz9hzxzYGrY7BKPhwZPJIBQag2mcUZ9GnyNgTd@SZkILbNj3PRccSOBojy328@/Tja@G1NPvYAKSGtjm9lrymsReWOepcj6Gzz04ePbrummGfKq7DHt1EScuy3cnYPRhfh59juz3TMZiullT9umceiDk27WK6mF7wAr9H1ghK0xClVp6XjDMZtMwREF8U4YU17qsQ4cTlBGeuY8@YOQVggGMXgpljZmFpsVw6jSHh/9hsu05nDh6cTIADcM3BcDxjCnNcwQPg5Y6YNzTaptIxbWtgjc0Osy3Azu0KbDwGBc7OzNmFO4KCVzgrEiLe0GxbXQujiBx4EjLbQ7M16TF3Mh5OAD2PdSzPaNkQrDVjHbNrTOxxkrXAD4hH7hd90xEoWU4P8/Fi7oIQHKgCHPtNDWhj2TYDdM4QHUzaY9vocYHuGLRlEpZmB0Htz8kFkAzb83O/mPBCMhjv2cjtjYwBMGrHJBp8dvCMeW13BDb4YVheC9aBaRtjtr3NovtPH0ZZLSCjOmpJAUmr7JIxFvE92blhT0yPDYwZpO2MoXIxl8rPjyFBcBbdiJZZNJNhepplsywLla3I9FyaQZUogQFqrZ7R4JdnepFlNeD7XDSJ6XRHRs@yTQ6l59pdBFRAjtVzTId3OhtNct82pVFgmSLLF1ghxwrwLrGSDokgxCzTSjn45eEHEEqAgQa/TJanFLAFshNkge2xrjGw7BmHPhwi@DbLaawAEAFNDSDrRYBQ0hHC4hOGN@4DYfvGOYBUbOsMxYUZSAwsrRR8UltbKRJZKBt5kl7ftG1MFQgFJMoVWQFSzUOms5Ay0FEv6n7me33KPuFVSMMPcCxAjotA3jRQKo2kKsAP7CCGdJA3OggXHeSFroG7DuYMQoVwefDLQ1nlA9LqHaItSFeIqyExUaBoSAOIxqDoMlkGhZeF4s1g8eYyDPAEBAp5BjKlqLFilhULDMhVSjMgvQbIYNlrIMs0QEJDYFCkGpSpBohowCwaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFctDz@IB4UvAZJapCmrpfmrAW46TnIZC5DPKfnofAK4AfE0gFXHbhFB2z1Ivhj3CIQrogsWfAJYdjDvoG0gBJARgZWA4LkACeCDeHBrBcynKUodMscW23pSoJaxVvAsMTxpQdKAJAmzGDYgAIDzrknFkjAOAikRWE18UwbuAhkSNsAM7It1HaUHD4ca6yinIVmynTPsSGl6r@QjEciojXCVhTkVcccjRiGhcbWS5Iw8SYtz3w9wbZ2jlcXpJMJgrVrWHaAAFUdY0ztAHyjHqQ3W0S7O3IHVL8GKCxs1x2uELsgmi4Q0CfuhTlHfS65jOHQBnkO7iYQYmLYgMyFQfoAqQvhVDlCEAnjtfsWAKSkQK5aI7NNtBdZh9gZkMCLKJaZXruXQSgPQs1Chg1dEKoexnEmtl2G5s5ss0wt1THPU@jCm47FJgNx8BsTaA8FiJYBbTk1pohFAOmerlIzdeKXrOcOFrPGxctBkPW@hU2AfWHMoPS6IFnMqTEAjYNhs@5Awz0AjuEliCXh8YbngHVcJzoOoFyMoHmFTAc5AZA20WRsDUzQx1yIgiWeJaRRuBFmrRmwMlErq5I6xjG5RihVuk4o7pANOfDKAg1bZ9JGqmHalkMcBA2CR61VDeBypVNFA1S5kWl0eDDULhCjkH4ErZ0JRBeqQJsAoYZiOh5oO57KLFQLgeF7bhd4jJpoUDUg6jydNuUdcx44TdW2KhGlkW8GZzazWHs4ZOAO@gmg9ShdhDbWfWWxN@Bp9z1mtyej0YxNh1AA1gBCjdtutwtM@8Yc9gEEG3RYe9aGWgm5RKaROi5JoPbwWpYD26YJYRwTsr337OusZwK1oUXuAqbE6fMMDIeUBSKF4fDW2jGAUpiF9nBGZAEwQYyu66ro3nFNj3gEtJmgxmNintmjGgHVqzuXQQPUPoA5QSNwgGVB4IhahfAxQWlpZjApUfgfmw7UmDYwI9R1KD7UR3dZF3T/UGONyp3RbpvDsWAPl6SY5YQUmsNHqNCQqyKAqV5f2rwPutgCBhIElXzOCbXgxhkJV1T0Sc8yUMSKDga06Y4ZqLCMCxR7diN5CHF@LXX5JYZZwOClvAKHIdUE1O5INkzGKEFQKFrtPorAMQoZ0jKgko0mN7MPbuHkRwOmdIO0ERsNpI2kpgInxGM1DAV@9k1A6tBGWLUFBwy64HALaMMbLIHsBkjanbCrmjJUkIW3AR24jrsEKhAzgItBFn2oLIgZj1FqGHbAjFRdvIUyQjk97/ti@wVN53DojqBmcKEzQ0nGiyzEXS7vp8SCJiIO/ebFFhVaiii28@Mx73MNbegHURXDmgr6pAGSAoQY7wGAzHN5iiGEqdYTLIHfBUl8zkzQhDqOiSqpMZpxIJA9aJUhoRmzRiMQg@fYNvCmx29DVOJTaAqMTgclK5KD6v31xFXk6L1Jy5pe72a00VF95Unnxoh1sYcxAl0DKlEs2vWi8Qq5U8yQl5xyh@MUReVvGQJSIBWKPNaFTgs0BI9A0BzPnHZMXqhicpLJk3G3KMfBgBG5asa@agzH17F7BW7INIMzqNdkq7AetNqKAm8F3QgT9Eip6GGMQL2ASghadqnUaRnsLUiPEVOmexQb1UL6amo2SMt0OkFaghCISzi/Kk/CG7XJoIRaNcwBBqecUyOxQMA7UoIiyuCQSon2Ex1IyeN@pM5wx4lDwwMsxjWQOLsMVHRoAGKEjAU6h9W2xk2hpdy75@srG9UqMBsoUSA2O/Gwcu@Po6ggqSGwSkqISEQdu8djrBuxOOQXA19xbEBbAk6t1tjluD@CGkf2KwkCAVklBznZJ6wo56fW2aRzvaAddMRAMtY60JWs9liuSND489pQXUfV6AJVQfmPIlWReTE@gb7BvOSKBSqLYCPTQ623KlAJlXAMMRC8upREPKpwmzP03qxtC5WAm6Cyc2nUAvTPRE89EERJoRP4lfZGTeVAsDpwOOzZ7sknVVEXuWeqZTnlBQfbbRs2OW9icNmP@/jgwdHu0debS2DYVqt83SFlZYt5bGonU6XnTFJZVS9vhmHMAT9sroeNERfDyJLwZoo7DalKszY0LlOfnIdHn14nCWhCSA5KAcz4u6bS8DCgdEktw@tfa4RZL5GAJIMoflimHDAfZmBA1NHf8PF5NnnzBgvvOlJD4Y6Y2RODA/AdUweOH09Fz2sKmO/V6vIWkeKCFmo5OP45N4VD@vh8jFrzdWRIlQ6xzMeHj/aPqgS2b3hnpm0rFCTljUGXMkYdFXjennRMaVkYEH9garOEOkcc9WnCdSmB2@0FAs/Llq2ADwCwi6O6TLEHfta8PuC@dz1v5Kq0Aw4gO0G4rleG9aH2hyIawgObuDb2dJe1ouQxb6wCp6UtVuC72Gy1czmzkC2Fm632PM1OGOiAlGLL9fXGEXideQq6qHMtUqjVAv3jxzcQ90iJhK6A4mPm2UyltDxbwt6LYrGol9qDHpprm@oLkngyk@OpVNQf@FTbHvU5Q@H3p9Y4lo7zrxaHsJD67u6B/tAPLAbqaACDOg3YBceWadTFiYa2BzziuLbbc9kWxOHaoZ8gqE0rs7nbc50bJWSgI2Y1gjMXIH9xvMYYQltjvaGOI8UKd1f5rIfheBcgpbV8BolEFCJQKQqvvjLODSDXPN/HB9/Yh0ZEy6XTgTlND5AgFIfIhaZ2yJUcmAIJqQKfpRkMZjFu1HbfQwlNI2CmhaALIu7OvZc6ksRUU0vDL0Xpq@4Nir9yZ9dYC1w4a4EhRLKDp88eHzzdf7L7@elYz@UW7Nl0KQ@Eg/RaoAupfU43rK1bvGpithBcBOrGCKsXSIEJdFD84fCJNwLBrWIQlSOwgmv4/E/sq27fiXrx65m5QF/lldPmLPQEKx8PKiJCR7tjY2dkxKfNsD1H/umPx0OvnEpBLe9PWip0WlOv2q5t9FIUDxoG205p2HU5OMRxDW9ZDEDGm5k8Bh/TAtVhRgOHhj1wofNCU3EoGliMg6fBKtvq9aEvjPN15iiuBhxMuUl1oIcAfeVUkDcSwGQD2oqvX04yZ@2vaHqR87WW1rMp2Q@2UP0h7EbXhK5TDForIEX8mpWd3ju9x2YgpRHSdSARpm6JKRtsC2wGiiQNlmI/3ycOSQscJkVZQTR6PcFBXJBSqVw6W9DyuRR0y6CbBjqrgkNtysAYt/vK2FUAnuJ2adwgxIVdr204XXVLGHxkQe/7CLKaqX9xeuo0QEE/vUe44URYfdaoa414hd2MsiXCxyvAvQvZQ971HYB3yQisSV@2Qp51jJvirGNQ7eqw1HgwFG2OMmRPdkGReuOCvO6Y4bqHEVJhz9TWQtgUBn6XWjIgZGNUCV9IqRRUKGhpgfVSiJcCSi@qh8A5ILdCEdh8NIPng08/h@QIdrqR7y036tFYPeo1OEjqDYGINMbcRint4fjgGFrHgPNRSkPhopBmF2YUh88Njw9SQiQx6ejHh75aAIEG44OBaCeYbAUmoFjUPQfJAXyFo6X9@SgjdvqB0yBBwgkHH0CDcGjSoAdyBiLzjOzyjPCUyGUxS2eOe@EgtJbJikrLGvMxfncywsk8qxPOGwTP6DwMQKPMheQ6zfq1zDYfZeWRKRfQCTTYwBy4OJQA2hWJApOyYPAZQ@wLejhQDdUqreDECcBX2P09kGJtk48XKQPsRAFL7bPoeJTaVb6RMpQ3wM1rdCvM/G54ApsK/cQnAI1EBjPYNEoiRkBJO3EHFOgFjbeg5wNf3ZWGs3EfcgwcJhtVd2g61/t8vEcYi1donjUaBYFvObHL6MbGRrQcrUWTYNoB0zaadtCUANMOmRQyYTgVTRQjSSb0rVMMdGtEr@o@5Gm8gTwwRc3hjTWMGfVyOdNIGnVNfHX8xqEogPIQWsEPwInGq1U0xuNy7QKnakB/D@V9D3nnuD2yhoIEXwWFgNsFDTJEBOjeozY/MivYN11PkUF1BJ1GE1XM2Ch6Wk@fNk4vTzuJ06toEmPHK0YV@ocgvMaxgdobuZMhKG71bFkB2RavZ8qNSqsaTUe3YrGiYkNCRjz@UTGeMDitY1ETeCp2ehoFkgrq1Nv9EcGbJvV4PCAU4NG1oJdh27GoelmE9FvxRjwRhbjxaBLEcjUaBbq0kQgeZRpHBDgTPbKmQEqomNDEhecUSEDSnBRW12@Yw/5sFA4QjLqBlo0j6PPJeKgMJMXDUvINjx9W6BZ6@r7ey8OBcouDd6gvDWdcuksc09PUwsIQv909V7oDd2ykPlOh06SGmsvoRjSlKNASkg@HRNl@YnlYhQ3HdCdeeKRx6QAopg6uJ/0JCEt/1UwSuMoaSma777Lo5n2AzoJpHmxKcMZK4fNePoBOW4UfClHUSnCyBLQLWk5igVzEpSZ8VEYjJLjo8cfmc/nhazVIrUJxWBoTsnqOOzIVIAnEkGjxBy0VkmpMrCg5oJGvG/MSwpeaNOx4WyZIxEe2axBtubgOzQcNB6H40D@HKEdmR7JBfnRBPKq8LEZmJ7Ul0eSsO@pDCwG5QUmsB6U1EB4p1xt21PEUokoxbHDDnrx3B0rnBevoup5v57pl3w@5Aojdh0LCXqkDXVzfS9HAMy4KeZ8PC/l99KeHD/f52Ak1tti84jhac@B2JqBXin7Tken0kmwf@Mly3IEFZPDjvzmzj1x3zHv5YFk1MsM7zdZgYhs05nN9WGZtvLbbcm0aCloXdR5@MvIM2@CDUL7v7mdPQNd/fnJcVcuhQCnjfLA2bRyHXJ4sp@dBeM6Rpln96SGPM6a8mZOx3fIXo6GYER559JiIpWhQRr57Ad39KoVzKMK9iO4DXIYGurIYRSBr4CgCliggLk3DFT3C8VJLX6H7yj5YEE6jcFxxnGN7qenkfj7udhecM@R8pqBosufOWXLmS9QW@ohhlHI8EK5XWwgTBpSnMMGytevhhPAKlhj0TdufQTwCxQRnyaBtt1F9gr4JauJ87ZgJivQQJ0NIQuMUG2uDrundGLaAOjVUeGgpskH1BNqwFGou0maKiSHuCtUUxxVTkx6Xni507Wn0ZLvGJ6yx6zTivbYUH3zfbAKI7VrFX020KhimFI0GwQgq4QYxKJs0bX8jq8EiDI/G1CWKUpG8FPQapnpaOZ0W9hspj4jQZfLp6fSjtP45dD5wzdfmvVTPrGByK6lFdj4O3e6D2GCJ6SLJoBwmTte1Owqf9ILyZ7y7hAUhlhoEq85I4IOLNfIXnFm4iEUsDARxGVqrdgPutaKr3QwQWt0WAILacMneniXP37I6tGDnqje0rXGDXaljt9nHzI8nI@f6OjiuUo5GxsyTxEqVKts9@vizerrBIUgDAyeyiry0pv4yStCDQe/B1apgwvU2Y2tMDTstLLAwv5oKSE1pzgPQBxg8gQoLEhI5QtTfmm/neema0PGMmYi5NxskmRm/Uru2MR6bDuctPpu4mtx82kckU6Xkd8QcQpmlaaIFFE0L/QDFCjs@ebh/dKQCh3qx6D5OyJSh2hntPugbqzLtUzKc@TL7qBNlH2GcOPbCJahS0JloivjAvBVgbuhOQOooCnrmKAaOcZxLaYMzTV9RRK5wCQLhqqn2mGgUAIuZccgTASsvxf@5w3tOAs8yi7IEURLIHbtXBtpacXXiWK9VD9oNUkMhSJT3PWmJbHUzRuJrU4sT/4ysAc4FQ5eJtEDIQ73ONkC6UWiZVd@xL@pppdRIbLJGo8Jn@CEi6vS05FYs3zQEPfl0GAlIgfOB6JV1ry3i9VOgkVuMxfHTgGclwbeA7GjSmt2spfKmLscDZJU34MA95etILllkylH0lzaRCKGVUIsrmhbXS4Wy9Zw62dcWh0N2fASC/OA0ZIznkm1UmRaP@5hxQC@MEXady@yZ63lWy6bVq13b4ivBgsa6LAgjIPmUCSdXwYpBdMP6DPUMC2O@ZJkvBBaUIH9qaKAnhTkjh1icXSIxiZQ6UpG9fYsOMtvUGbGBjCuGOX2v/D4tyMfHLiD7WKyADuscJDTE8hQUHaeS7HfeFud/0Yd3DFLn13Re5VwOx@M6p@WcuTSLFJiaaVXLoZ4ZxB6c2Tdjdi2vT6@FoAEOPKy@Cjtv0OrSa0kAmkwR0/TkQMP0QsOG4jRSR/ShEfslKS8uTVlItmV2J06P5jTRzJTXt4RUSkUK3G21rFVBgQi42sz/LgkGshJrnq5mVc2vPTjAA80iyE/eJ5pn/fqqJrZAd2ikxhBLfP/LNztA/5ul04f2CsczA0MTNAUsKaW7srBEVLTQa3nB8mH3iW0ZRBgy3QaybYwgS4YdGJaDpql9RQF9Y4ATFaLEgTfxBbroGjbjmPN5Rv@7PJFlU3UOyO32qrDXVnnxpGhSCbqLHSIC17kskyKRkOWFYE75xE6o444C93ak/KVYjJiZl3t/Mp7wN6jDtxaiNcTfuropQqZzRkszoUNqtCxzTZGPjLNJx1WGZ71ALc4vCTvPPc0sK6CViEnmJhqXZ59ncGT1oLn3v6uCzdvX1AV9buMKz5l4Q6VFffsOt1FFGKxJYWTz96ogltipFBhWU82y6XVHThTQgVHEGosUrmBVQkSzrpHZNlozVIX6H85lwXoFkDjVdiKRzqyYsB4OV8fH/inFL5WWx56qbU6PZSMPKb5KVuFjc5RhsW72llKF5soaGLaid0LGlcJ82XKHG0GDmVKKY57jPNH50pKbUx8bpPbENkZz0xoWn@PhT06sGucWzYaoy23Xtjys0PYqqemvuZunheuU6RVaV2Eto2QHOqLYjiuBabkUcNtjXIu6gq3uINP4GlBcaRviE9VdRay2e4G/lRpEHzrD/L28UXuzFKs7yCfFbtsGNOUrW4SFUUcc1byFVy8sz6TXcsKeLUV03LaXui/WAn88MTw@eBtne5bteuyY3usI1BsBFfh7OU@HaWkZjkKj7GHzGjHkL56YF6hh91w7X@ylDHitLPXJqIuiX3zvKuQCIaVptwgpXwNyHU18V4r2s9To7LYCov1fI1w4GzKuaWWXSSoxqbM6d9A3wBnB5Tl7lC5STDXFxxBXJIxzORfGzP/@Aq3HKtL6rcdwRho1KHgYoVQEw3jEtexfJLXs@tQ6dxNKN8AWbstEqHDPbBPaK3rfKFKmp7UPjKGl03cXUV17Yk7MpX2Nw9YrE7cRr@ln3B2ptMjGppgCwFkH3PMShHojOod3whqbarStFSYG9NrN27WZRaE2BAV8iL3nZ2B4hoabMXrOZLhQqgsdNOdoPcn6Q79Ku50F7NDnQ@VQ8RZlaUFF90z6re008U4erjyrZtPptNBhQlM5C5Z1nalMEPeVxd8LCZPLPOV5WJy@G4WMy9MgsoTXNq4UQfqqvj0FLpVSjuWY4xm@7yhNW65rf0hJgVDtWKiNgXJJa3jXldgNdUfsTmHz0QsPxzxa3VXjFry1Ed1LoA/2m9cVeniu6U6lqeBs6gBnuhat60dwQjNXt6WC27lxWIiv6rVX65JiQERTi2phba3jGqrbMm2Df6b57Dp4JTWzFt6i0BCzwDhrzOeK53P8kWtCaTgDYlkd6Kj0zYFJ1jWKvtF5NfH8z8pAUxd/q7ynptlOTffN9qoAQwvkgoPvhcnpkLI0dh3oYo1xASF2VWxcoipcV0lgfzpxKZEPBkbP5GdUrJOU8zELXKbDe3Zz4/LRizJfmtOGaPMR5tUsAZXqzJx5/ncpwCezNpTrZHD7iNu1yt/GYdA71PZVa2NvNrFO3@07fbPPF6QHtlWVA/hxzM8UWYc6YN3r4xq54XBh7XyYnrZr23ehJ4pGLihdt7sUp33cVYtbwj4I7sxogYf43Dp@Z4y57EDDylrTNyfQLnnu2B2aCtlWBbVxrIe/V8lQf/b7Fx1EWtvVB4r4318U/q19y57hjodD@jSH9sSjF0VVaDP0bXpTl695odWW7qinvnEHLVU4qmJBDE26LxcxLWvc7uMmdM7ZZs9ttfvWbUi3TGPsWGcpf9SHW@/Ud0XKWEx5iM6qbQF5RzMV@aUa9j/Gz8GqQhcDSLxZCwxr9JVlg3S031sZGmdtjw@IoomVcUw4VBv5rvAybacvv55Y4znQ0CKpYISXz0ygYRXuYlnGSs2KNl/MxbBYrrGSS0lJR4VcMdOg8Ggrx5cWFtCFqlgmw1@rEArnkjAKLXj5EHKLRUU0QGiFhm7BfYG/FlZDLW3knP6k590UmHzEvgMqGr5WD1vQIunQqDW0WYYjPqvIrNsp3D0J3yboXBNz7bRKbu28CoXTbMVwLfg04QNFN1k5hmZbQ4@/mdJdORsnFklBX/z6lCGnzWx5Z1oUTMfs8lkQNN2mIg5cmqcFHURp45w@DqKjMOeKFxdcjtsDoa7YbB7YD7tKbVm6/mh58QdtpvL5U7Nn4CLux9YYV4Eu4Qpi2WXrlm6F/bWJ4Vlfm0DOVjEbHgXBZyJH4TMD0LYE3hOjZ7U/WSiIAElBYLGElH8W2B@dbpbFRd/ycA1VYFgzMIUsx5kYua4J/YYlIa8P3QenYMwrEN9fuTT0suF1dzjDbWgzMq0bWbfGNMoqvqu6jqtWl61F4mIyGE488VmOA63SCo9CD87I3buwALjyGkQr6xv2ePlIdWjIFbQw0SjOjau08W9Ytttj3yimGShtoIShcr6EcR5A8/wMlwaNnCWcSGnfceYTBzqUEc/YayhbM8MUy7HG60dzxmNcJuR/MTO85cCtD6nH@FbvfygE5WQ5RR7fruvP9zzf0r4D5x27k1HbRGNwkEm4WyBSNff8Zc24VcTFg1guwr20tbM30By6zmSsjCbO2lYhv7ZVKLNpMR9iAxb72v6T5/EwN9Ay8Nu0UBM6fxPPns1NK9cMXGMyywFFbLUcXQzt9yUe8nOXjmgN8i1xdvFwqDaJ64fusv7Os9nIHN@5wwTCfzJ4aLZx5vDWtJ@6T1zHhdZoCIJycGTywwQW1nosj4jRHuN2eaBP59ZkjgnsikaIaxvG0GxB@dpz013aIg74oTE2VjRFNDZI/b/AdCuvWHbLHL2iQb@QeVWXdhGhT8wp9S1WMwyvg8q43eYqMY7HLdSRhRkbb@i6Dn@TtE3DR3uyXqpAU0Cvu8@Vq7jCf2FcYGn/bDGrh@d8oYjZ4addrMrryGy5Nn@vWZbkWHxZgDGyTC/1GA9PILd8limgfXlrZUhhrQyZd41Akz03PJqnX97VmIPUph@wCqhvjNouzoQJw5oFOqETD24R08GmAb52oAWEn4LEMtoTcfbibWjZg9aAXis7DKHSPDJbuN2oRceEjI3pzcLkI0PijITQoq7gZAFfXGGlzrPYM@iNxG9vthb6UYtUtYb0Ikm9crqc1usojmW23xg4auYSveZj0wv@kOfUUzKuGKsOVSMaRU4ZtIV@aU1aXL0GCo1tKuP@CPr8qfG64W3//JYl8yGTgYmTzIuzMCtVV9frU2bd5fPpgXAdmYo4OxBkSXCOINcPld2VmieCh//DB19NQSPczGf9M01AdN0@gw/IT0aO@NyFA5@53rhrTQ8Bb9x3sEqcYLZyEAU@vGagaWtVJqD0nInNRx96oaVXgw51xxQ6v1ZRbBLXY1MxnXOFTpib3syRy3eTpXbxMNSx2VHEAQs406A89jeWBcHEd8kEalg24npPLcUJO81nxQrQZcS98CUD6FvuWBl69E0NvWcHjw9P1KGnLW2fdvu4H@OGHrdwYoNeTIeGpF4Zo9B8J1@R1rG8cerBsabsPT5QMcAKevMZDQU@ODO38Fk57imOHjVSxspeEPqa4@UK4icnTx4n5ns/WWyvP3IHZjzsvXd8nMS9LV89Xuodjv0IakfXna6MfrCvafEl7PvcodnBVdJzSUqrIJ2Y0BsFZvyEH/hyq3LVdodm52Q2ND@DxhMluHfH5PMrM/nUOLd6WAtZaSWhqKKykprPxkOLs6GzbY6C76ryPLOGKC3b9Enxz8rlKKg5ZFKjzHLtYd2M/3UthqXFSoQPi6Slb3Lr2FKgZvT6aEoZ3t8XMU3TVtH52OhCubLcysJaDLBsfth2z@8wlWyKzosSOClj4CrFunUpeUEZgOhO4QuH54UjGFsrl8GsAxA455dW@AvTmRmOQnNZ69SLMsTGRW1rg3zDvMOEVLDC5xwPhF46xxesqmexNhnjtyR8MgpF2dt7cHBbhCNBy/WhPn76nD0zPDzdZH3AMMbmHTCea0avFBy3wqP1Vk6ndkYASl8LrzdcXp/L7NgYdVxnNr19Eo42t2LTTocVB7DQRoFM25pay9qqNh/XerZ8mdFtafN9HO5sQQ8On3ojAL3/zj/TtHSazjTCr5bm1ltKxq/gLIYmY4YH5YW9Tg4C0dBGvUUFh/jS3uhjc4rLUfho8LJO/dL2Lb@m7SvEVzcn6/yKa/yya9K74YeOLKOmtTUAc2v8WE4NvB@79kXfVfeMkendsUxCqK3LEm81@fano4kTPpDXS4ojFfiuRb6PzFP9U5NjMSeRiMcXD@YP75rj@8Xw2Da@1QvCvn3LNsSOLvAINrmJfWR4uhOolybuvpQIBG7viznVqpYrsR08Hr8MjUecUkQnOkPHT6vONi/F9qxyWbvCLWpyWWZi@1xwJCY/1hHg4oF0kCemnGlscww@m/7mLkYHk7O3jBRSaAG1XBpsaiq827Yidr0BSpuXzw6e7R@f7J48P66nG1dyXOzt5Lg5DqTm7/r9KNORIe@CbMDo/JBX2h1qQ3J0aDoqsp6fLwY5u5a16kLW5pmSdzDO5qXjpFK0yTGlXAF@isxTI19otdCJw/ZzTOUj9qiW@d5Am0gqb3LQMqUJZVZm6WUJDw3Pg2wJ/@vXNpAvy2TQlycszuUEVu65bkek6Jns9sdP8dHuwePnR/vMR3DONBdWZ9yvlnL82FZsDBQTyqlr0XqJKouKKFEoq2o1@igKhImqUVamraV0ZCrwOQTzqYObUkXsLRbbJPhAwWhQKKn/8s3UVVTFpX9xCBv1kYoyQXkMwE5wu9if/aTDjxT3D4nw7yYZDUjy0WZ8SWwFXbERFClKFXO4@oYSOsKb9nwGZ4fPb32R6ER54MoLOt/p2tk/cTqOg183I45m8hMiBvGPIcYxJDxmCTrA5xZu@OQ4dPHUo0VWxmlnOulLZbt4/QrwPDPoWHtAfeKM@cki4hyCCPCRGgiUJNskZPkh@HIoYHR7A1i5ZfYsh3kOKObmuMxeAZ/hOE2Z7zpWlFr0RhQfNL93R@mPB3Yo4I1jkrzU6Tj1/te@m@pVGJin6Qdg@xVh64L5V7n5ixSW9c2jlObph5HA488E1jzxgOZI79BNMw7f3T0nFp745EtKZg2gaM6J0hicp8DfCgjYOZxY/TMoKGAxKCWxq5unZ44aMTx/rZxKIRvhnJdKK1nNKV9Wcu0ctnwun9VSgKRy7gOkg5N7uGWOA4zHy8D40rk1rL5sAXttbzMZ9Tyzmq/w0kxtOl9k5JcBopsQVrroI3J1BnEgyjwG@NVENGhOEloco6I8impRFEUdF9oZ8sf2CO2OIITMYkAsTiMTT@Kd4pVD49HMP0@whdf4hA7V3xSAFA1aGTLFZUlsRH7qjoFlFrZg843IuKyKt2l4UJfHr9SiY/yQB9WbtWm@f84/vV/ULxXrPQeVSV9vHsNlK79AEMcIoiwvY9n6F@x0fOo0Upw3GbDpjwTLhpnZAfM/SfVW8CzP9@7NQ9xi149gQ2Kx@8eOiwrtI8gMi@kpPZPS8vF5lrLZpVkSORLJQHbwaIm3kByIJhATbdN65Q693b39g68ePju@cVAZhYxeDwaSvLadOFXUZL0RGKLhbC0WyYNHqeMnDx75BTFHOh@SwKC9iJxo63Iy76ciyPm65@tZW4bh9dytxvgF3xx5Hd@Mvg41inQDDy39AenS2kPlEe0guJ64XlxGrVxuHUpzeKkQ6D2@/esGqrH45VW9sV07dSLRm5ywpCJ8EVG3sBKA6dTb2kwhs9/MHGYsuPruBC/t8cJ1MbO8LsqbGTwvBzegjt2z@UlBwiHkEcqvnwyISElN@UFX1r5DrnXPz7PS@dV8/GSd8HkiIYTz6XUUD4E68W/5QykyP41PHETXh96ibbUk/xwXfiCdf25WcBYdP4MlFpfEme484Zi4929anqq00CAWR2lHsJJs3dl2Pry4BBUa9bVnE@i1PnOH/IxfmlB6aPqmIxfE78MJn5k22VcnAwjXpc@RSYN7ILkViAyUjAaocv0JpIQ42m6awMMDIb06HnAnMq4OOrnYNK72zWnH6oFsj8WTINE@0rQGC46/w0zTcXdOVKYym5fC2qr4MW7qC5P9g85AnM4RMOqGajkdcxqLXkTj5Qakj@7Rixfn0bi8jJfoLEZxOGHn@qGMAfoFbb0kMcaidvonHi6TFqXSTSkBbtcB89OE/AtGSiW170l0T1QVdfHj8egxGEGNiHUHxpDFJg4/cUllZI2dxpwkHVGj1PihbQ5LJKiLBB/yUBnF7JKJt98xw5mxWKoKTICuntPBzxtryOqaqjbATInE2SZe/LMHGheeXhKXoFcLUcoEtoosBB0HwIhXEpUzOMRBfwkPlRnRuVVLvOkeFBoDcZEmlGtWu8dC9zctao5yqVQWBbooFUsMuO@mOFRTAPaGnPN1eaCuOB0BaAYdWlWKzAX5TYkXoXQjHJFPxLEKgE4kdNCif9oCA1jzYxDb/RH@YvsO1BU8IKb8/ORRsxhPySw4nqE3sjo4RsfPCg46beJ2B6imqYWg0Qrvo32M0fDcrSY//wGPhXpEFUa@JlIjYTJcv810zpuatpbrRURRChAyiw2A2MPS9MHhAXP@bOkSv@XC/uc/x/tS5djmTj7TtM8T0Vy6Ai@tkmM59tHmqaJs1vVcunp/s2EY41OZGans1sNzs99tHfRSp7LMMiybSm3p@ddnQy2/9UVdfT1tyPViNXnWeHbGnj37/F3zXVyens/k0xgrRNje4VtZgwxEygVWYvhb@tBFhkufNb10OQpwT0/xHlS5IKdS9WgD/snrJTw8UL2m1tSdxrt38XoB8jSdnUbwekF2eJ@8qZ9EI026Hj@2LCvFTodepwM/t88a/ILcCH8SiZjChINS525sMO2S23TX7PUm@8aMu1uRCX4ejUXcJ9948eIFGl7Qw94cifgcOvPTKDeNXITpaf3Pfrpxlbx81tz@s28NUuYGfg7x892rJ2g@1nIfbWx89OBBNpsEKnHzs288@/ru7m72YTL3rJ7bySrpje0//ZONDV3f1lMbDc/TGtH62dnnsp7Oyuqf/TjafPbsa56HxYJPhmlgxHcRfhrqVGfsDTxnXYb/ZH7TCZkNNLe6b5geeRMBto7M6K8ZYbwWVklLCj8bTKvtFP7r9w9fR8aRmp56MYLvOPI6ki9GuBEMYMv4tvNILbKNwfJXkVmqWq2CsfBf/x3Er30V4KDPbBtetZwPKz@L1JQqRXkbqeXBoOk6pPt/ffObtwz73Gd1eORsQZd3GvBs0bMt4aFYSjqVuhZcK97T7jHmjPtj08WPxT8OfJhRcaDXfVRPJBINVYFHbVKklKbppzRgE2YtGm@JBM4Vxl1YyG3OJ8IF/F5EiKeAqYivuFk4EKtxhxfXw71Y8lRe/EM/R1Ikv3HffFirgSjM1DJbtQQ9G6flMid/ihWKsuvel7egyNL0eszgAwKzJjOWLupyMpm83wStUkeaKlNBv0j0VI5GIi/nJPUpG2FzGws7RQQpWVAHf4Fw@/j8@f/25z/48@/T3w/o9x/x/DCnY3VTWwyvymbnNf6wWk2ujeTLU7LcZ@lysVxMNdnVaWyrXmscMS398dtoLhM9xkZCo1CncX@EMxI8tRq@fDTQVotwlxo3zd2ETy2wUIh5lOXhmJBMjIlEoAkWy6yU@jnI2Jqfo@mNh9XvQyHJeqEkN2p6Tj@syWlNpmIrsf6mx9yIyNEOPBvwR//w7ODgsXDB9wY5ch8KuuTZCFC5/VmovVKkXk81zAYosqzmA7m/Ud4olvNlHQplNeDKKtCR87A0UQtqUdVBfLyrb7AjzusNlvCf08Stz3NVbQojGVz8KYo7jUiRf4CnJrHIJTyNd1v1d8C6Ium6qKeJbaVRSwiM4KM27zcSytVVXf0iUamI/@1aYKzQw02QkcaVomx/AbDqN6FyoPRWm19sA9jEdn276u7RT20iiZVo1o3m3fuNL2r17UUQAsr9@wkUtfcBTm0TmDSeSGwqykZ9ZR4AcCMGSsA2FODV9lXtqr59dbW9Df/b9L4SX3C92r7xT5/5syLM3J@qzWk9VTtNnQq2aYBdTdXQRU2dgqEGXwgHzZAUAcVkKkW22FZkyLRCBkzMLGtbeiaVm36U3wfVqN5QsAdTVepaPtdQuKR6qbKywg8d14r5uIqiqOl2m7hPUGUvpcjL91/@L/g7ff/l72O7D9WyJEVSW9g9KPFeAryeOOzJkyf4e@I48A@/J/xx0AUdnqCbw18OD@GHCZy5C1YHEApM1ot5uZnQZjqLbMv5AoqFX7rxRKPRf/RSLxWivAeN@@leeuD4S8uef/RLqx4p8raE9bztMZ4nKUL1HsoC6k9NUWrbA1xGhSPTCnYCPqtOlee7CvZajTHNNbR5j6x6sF8tlWqeh@qiFLlEKK3X@Pf4Df69HuPfSRv/jl7jHzt5g39HY/xjT1r498zDv5PX@Lfbwr@TAf49eI1/T8b497yHf1KkCjr65k7aTrfT2pl2BgaLpUcs3U/3tQ52INImS8/SM5YeuFoHTCb8pcFkpbss3WNpJ@1oGniCYczSYzR14dODvy5AGcGfhRPxZ1q6zSAVGxscum2Ivm9B/sVPpTr0POWXJmjTqqam1bzVwEPa63JDLxWZigWjNusvT6MNPP1TL2VZa2ZunL5kEQ808UokdXqa4mMKTM9W8Dz3q6tmc//pw2YzhRLs9Il7OP8/PByErWv/B4fuk0N34ML/4eHhE2bWEvcTyn14qrXEtvjsRGqVndOygtXdlzCR1PbOaS2joDmfAGmho1viA585RPjWNk6lKAMF56JCalTl4rxyUSFDYAVDsxIEEMG4ARwrQv0Cl4qvh13Ac35BjvhC48WL08DEDakXF6fYnYB@YvAPemrY@t/g3/p/1/@T5yxWb4BaFLu82o7RE8e/ePzy6vJKvGvxWExYYtvwhw5gxyiXVzU0UqBLMNVj8Ub86oq7wTsW3@YAa5jGdo0izwNC7Y8EaVK6/BX7b/vFtMVziueEG/MJ/tPTaTodr7T8c4lxcst4S/Os8QrdMrPZqmuNP/0xnT69E6dAuWylom0xbtGzeqWS9W2FYqVS9C2bsVjp5lNL72h50Iuy2Xi8UgHLjg82DdYAbBHA@pYcQDU9o031vhK5PDikc5lBTOQiccwRFwyxNB3fjjeBROWyfO9eTNwwurMbv3dPL6Xfvg1chkNw0hacms2ONWo20T3z9q3clGnCvZQDe7r49i3IsmjcHcWe4gUykFBM0dhHeo3SLLkjIEQBvJmW0udY9A3PGI9HsTfWMCnjkiJPjtP9Dum0OzqN/ux73/rWabRalRWZXLMaAsBUWG57O5@t1fJZMOeLQCl585JfddJLlLT41WZK5tRg8mY0Iry0YiHOZWMU/aFhZDs1qOAePuzyKkLFzrK5eAykaxz0s6sI/nFnrVTi7iybjxUTJfFX3YizGqgO/A@7tZlEdquwdb/B6G@67EGRXLk0q9pV9dIs4@jgVaUtbu/DPYjmvXuZEtC0mK6cSs3mw92T3WazKssytofwQkcS7hJeGjQcRetU4LlSo475a5xGo@XKfWIOrZhjkWhFhFOi0EqwYonIIFld3GAMeZc0MWawIen0xZckhpA2wDGCLfr89@zx7t7@SVLfBk1If7S7l9SPnz@IaGjNze3knUH70f7uw8PnEOHZ4/3d4/2PDz7bf/4M3D12MX98CSze82/YtMR@wV5Ir0ZvDNM0zIlpNi8mk4vX7JVlNS0grD2xLMvtjZhnNk3THEIw/6nAr215xqtXxmhID3v/o@@8/9F/9/53vvf@d77z/nd@8LMvf/Ad@P0Eft/j3@/921IO3z/78p/97vvf/h1w/I/w@yP4/fRnX/7mN/mP7H8Mv/8ccvtj8QuF4z8JYP3Kz778/o9/9uWv/hB@/1L8fnjz92s/Xf77wbdX/zDe9393fZjv/Tv4/R6H5Yf93m9zN/zeCP/bPNyv/vD9b/x7/v@n4g@Nv/P@N/4YX8LyT3/4p//5/bf@g64X//TfvP/2999/@1vvv/3d99/@x/r73/w3Wjr8@t33P/iDv/rD3/urP/yf6P8n9P69u/y//@E//Yv/9S/@97/4Q/H7Kfz@PZh@@hf/ARj2b//gR/j//T/42z/6Ef7/z//qb//g1//2V/41GX6LG/7vf/lv@fuvf@0//c2/@O5f/fSbf/PrP/2b3/qDv/o/fvX//M3/9Nf//e//9f/4LXT8rZ/@1R/9yl9@6zt/@e1//pff@nLF@ztr31/ewf3LfwCXu@N5Fzh3ydeHunz5C@Hz96HGPBXgE@Duf/L@N38ZGPw3GHv/nZ/gSlr4rfj/ia5RmJ9w2/8HDPrNPKNPGkzw@/X33/kekuh/ABLBf0Cv7waWBR9u@e7cAmT9F9ciRczyYuNZ1IuJLehhbJVKogENvLcp5s@@/Oc/DpL45UWoC36Q4ndRUi34fRdl3PsfffP9j//x@x/91vsf/Qq2Zkq2lNxNKtr6MWtoApXcHcJhwPxdwkHAzz@H9KcJGmFVEmhjnwvPzz//XJq@TeHS7ftvwfVzcuIP417gx4SX7yfccYFrOAw3pn3jJjq/DSeNZEhgsglSBbZ8PSWXYdOEwGiKA3j4BXcINN0i4xTf5IreUwlf8/@5cSqxBIYRQ5eJuZEMIp5IghulHCSTmE59epHixLiyssVdaPKJ0s2WGOZgOk1MoUcKBkghAV4PEqxarSYwYpXjA1aOWq3ICJVEogr5xtg8TrJZRBDTBwQFYlYTR6y5VZ3yiAmEV/PJkZDQ6UjWdDlRrD6EBKvThwxhIXAC@/JltVasTmsI7h2nR2KaeEA4IbBqYlp7B/YqwUzgWNTDd4BKsZpI1IqYIGaSF0@yyQspR5mjvCdYQpQBfGlg9z5jH8laUeYTIRtIMB4a34l56B2amtsB/9PElsgO/ftG@m0RwTcoKZEK4/47pCrucO0RAwBcRVFVlcEPp/t22H3wnnJQCUoWPgkOIUEcQRwQOAAbYlkkqHwTZIH0I9WtD34SNYnnZnNzU4rU5Ix8SBNDCei1j87K/LqSt7xrVGZyviSjs0kLxnnuzM1nNOyw9XAL3hr872/QOu4EqxBam1EcE4wynh77KMF/9@9vsY8g9/Sdu0lMSWTcLI7JY0a3EwlZh1RrbkL6AqSbBOxLgN5K6rRK01EJKZlkTK1G0I8dHh4K1Mjhi6qUAO7XMxracf5gMplEIIaqJtVkUnxV@pKDKgwq@Yqvuok0pzFMpuvZCvRvKgydWLg7okG/FR3fvXsHhUVrOcoH0KNkYlmHni2SJzjwHa22PfO3G@jZksS700zL8wvFY3TfYJzFJRZjW3GJr/rlSPhPLKoXi1E0xaFM1NiWv8onr0n@0GKkhoj6D@/jFXNx33PvkO0dPnmy//Rk2GgwyaSLIM3mcOS2Tc9bJ5hjGG/36UO@KUAv5RGNSL2OKZ@UdRRL0n45TULz4OHRwXGZcZqIEooFkOIVGjYWpChpUmQ4fLEdESshZLyZxJWP8V2e5z@mlzKYYK0iRdomdkuA4fCfVaQnXu@BO4W@fFKWk1oeu2hxGnhl0tfdcrn6TssWJPiSfcLwDC2@4RZqJy4dV7e3iWhS7VKhwXI0QgHnpVpNLClimlQ73j@BCCeHTNPTKoOe/mW2oGdz2ZyeyedzBV3L5kvZfK6YgbYmn87pulbKZkvFUuFKqn3OpiriqoDZrtqm0xv3N3Ehj3yalkP02Kynk/inZzLwBohJLVdobGzYlwoieEpscYkrsq7AeqkgBb4CD5O@IrGvgBM8kAYus2JijdvBYUUsNMKjLWJ8tZGs5aByx6VTYCQOThqGn8oQqg909kM/KbLxjW@MWa0GnWzl4JEUASnVZ/5iG8XqqH2V@KgzGZnk22OsY31m4X01asfyhrYxg7qZVqXI1dVVFyAdPGJ6TScrj9HB91WbXFpgvpoa0v///GJPRFFq0vawBuy4nRqC0QBjdjtlgLEFxtx2qgVGC4yl7ZQFxkkto6W3UxNoJaRtfiwUw12nVXlsTvEUOu4m1zzT7qq4q6AqUwK6vC2OWayJeDXcnuEanSpuTcRl9bH4pdSpdtw2XZElddSW25mp3nhm4/J72x1Vo6CMRX0PC28dxc1c1TprqEN3CE2mnisk6loaJDT@tGJST3bUtm0ao51cOVdESzB3spNLly8sp@NeqJ8/efzJeDw8MmmF/062VO6oePYD7tLeKZZzuUa9LsuJOiXTwBv3ePVUNjaApU2jo8C36zpjT9GLDYjcsUbVajS6k9G0ciZdlK6CzEtANsxRTcJ4CcxJEkl3Kbi/7LgO1LRy0khal5Trcrfbvdq6TMwtknGpcBvQ4yphJFuXgbWihMKV2SSZsOae4GJ0oaG5FNNGZVnPFeVKvTK3F/JypXEl3R@YHcvAVf2n6csbkfJp@SoIc5rGYEsC5W8EOjVuBMtoWQwG9OFUAR7kx2vVaJVaHQRkYx/avXpj2z94C3lP1xU9o2Q0Rcvg/y0GHf/vHl6Hfx3fECujSye4@fQpyEloCBz2GM/5HrvsxHXpSrcHZntFiL2@Qcvx9kau5/09wjwwnDPu9dDiJz4FXp8YeJeDN7DG/RUhng8HuEfSHP2DQdgftABBqrIU4AG8RrbrLgtQYM@frcjlk@CMRSAGP2QRgh8dfPzJSeh7sr@794mUZw8Onz689smJQDn2eP/RSWAtcF8/ai4A8fX9x4@vW8UngioDDv1usFzBN2gSrue9Bx2me8KYy8@NaTS@4FvNLC9YX8r3FJalE3//mcFQELRM1ubbVrEHR8d8CEVOK5Qkacgc94IV0qzj2raB11l2N8Cxb@C@GhNVE5tuXcWkL9yR3bmwOuaG9AS38JQ0vLMPkZA@ASCDSZv21FtjCQ@N6uBFkzjV0LInJpvgZa4rHOGDTmgcWb0@iPkL1w8gtQyDwe9DH4hvhp/xeocxT4PcbvjYN4NLEQk1UGNsRIqVe/e0ZyPg7FoxXS73zLNybX8KnMWeA6cbI5S7mym2mZPb8iOmNiPGFqh7PavuNYasCGWXyW7lNVRdQNcEDYsliwy1LdSE6zpoW6cpI@s6lTfMHda8aPrKvILGo5DYyULrMO62K9gmtXNlHYRVpfzX/@InyM5bKZBcEU2WcZHxhiappN3qpWKuWMroxWSxVMzmtHwul9T0JHQeCiVIMa0VtXwxV9KSxWwpkwV1EXxzpYIU4Su4UlsEEr5lAOu08ca5bVKQ1X5NivBpKPYmZsRZxAjsEyabEEfGO8a9Me1i3LKqsp5lWppB3wggGqzNIo8e7aUfPZLlB2jByfe9tCx30JIrptOFB7Jsks9eEZt42eVxinhwhzzmlnT6wZ4sTzgAPPNSlvto2c/j0IosW2jZ2330CNPpokXH@BDsjPtwi@1bChDMQUsmQ2Mzsvw6AAfhdnlCWcJ0Hy2YJvo84j574CfLH/v4pNMA4YiH4xA@8fO6uyvLB9yyu4s@e5TxHEf1U7Ts0iPLI7BAVZHlHhh6I6ikstwCI1YYWW6DqT0zwA3v98ODEZ2xIcszTiAkkSxPKbTRPpPlpu@OyXzyySdGf9wxe/yZjfi3DaiBjzWd7D9qffxxq9drjWa7@x8foc/e3idGdzYZtXotEa3VhMeFOOBzNphdfwDHg2bTsJf6fAo@zjWf5qxpIm5N4zXgJJ4eJjJo7oHPHvgsm8Hj0OAZQNAWPg8G8H1gtMjHf8iHvtNWS64go6KWSZf0Qp2h@3KTA6M9citon1Y3GIvGoslZPZ9uVMiDDUCfTFeu6HbeGL4N7MvHL2f1aTXdqE6rBZ0v/ejG5NOpnrPk5MZgRyvlyhvGjqZnE9My7mV2u1EWVbQdFtPubb1hsafxHT2TLcunOzuKXNcaO7pWLOcLX2xNZDlexvdOplCGgOko9HTxFa8XGjuFXChKoZAwUnq5UIhXroAcY2hQWyhZmrHYhWmcxeOILvbIIAv8buAZ5dOqdGPT5LTK8WKzeGVa1Sr8zC6WvgGrgwdETtpjd8Qh9gDcdCddptuHZa1UlCH9VCoWj4NkIiEC3/l6sBdfOzk7OfkcZBb0dUVP8Rm/0rIirB9/sqdC51HY8GBH9RFq8@5I3UPBsuDDzx30nU5A6VU/gVYRFH7fDfeXjFxb3Z9C/x27BL6Hf1yXKg5ZUk8@WYBzDN1knjJuz63QqRBO22R47qXVYUa1Biajw2KEFTPiF9QeN2u1arM64BcI14JYnzI6FHIO5sDjuAebhin6Je65EB7Navqq0qpOI1OA06wyRXs5cDsv9US70sHjLh9UH2DkShO@rYpZNfEaZTkiV7o7TpWxieMZXfOZOcIt8AeHm6Ad4EaMWJeZ8U12Spcu76GWfaXURsyZY/Z0MogZSq0VX3QKWZE0sa/5Wb6knUE4J35V6VZZ7It45TVYR5ss1lEfxHeylU7sAWvGwSX9svuyy3SWz1boHroYQoJKRLShy4zj1dqnoNBwwGflMiAiyvgMYGJKANbqkIcRH1pXlXbVZjGFTVmcyJOt9Kp1jP0WX9uKLDcUpf62IdUU5YVUg3pamUWMqjdp0RnJLN3S9HS@MgU3rZCt9KFgjS@mlVF1OBmZFRusYtiEb4AyKkBOoBqAefM29v6XvxnfVnJV7lYhUG9t0CGaarM6rTh46gqwRDVTBY9EPZtOQocRXoUkNMg66AD5ZCaZTSoFdIXWOJlLgqMGukDMjsmMycn0NK1qSc3UklD7X1qdlyyePIuB@kEkA8vY3cc7nMEFCgm5kqzwNVg8oW/ZDErBZca2QmwKkqKCGQOa99nQSvYR1JFp2BQjHldYZitmb8YwzObJZLhfb5TL@9Ph18ArprzeyScK6cSbeLwS24hXPfO1VKtINZQqlOvhBvCsGFFi3mRQhzIeb2oFvVyvtzCHhXQyk85A9qzm2962XJMbyfRGXoMSumKkxzAuMLguM9dG5m5NVKLxQnSmlfSKpNLiCUpRi@mlVTtn4hIu2xMApaEQdkhhFjuV/S2AsWi0oEej8WgFx543ZDFkCBKO360OojZ6T9uRQX@Sy3JJxwBzQUm7vNJhFepKwg44y5akyKV0dXm1DYpbilbRgXLINsikqLX7UqTMGOhxp@IckdQGYx@6OC@xXfuCf09x1S/AlejUNNAZacmMaWHXiH2GO1p3WBQQM0aDuq5nGnW9AO0byEw/qK5rFRxZj@C6YrUGlPcuAb/tRA03g3zKZjMjofiUvcdYL7EpUaYj18m@W93tHe1WfNseDu6dSrIsV6Jy5DIaiV7BnxS5TztQdL4DhUVCe1D4qtW2CfR5FyGJwfYu/bGdMt7dETPKXD7UG/F3Ty37sphReDcfBNbVVWQzRSUiFvJXPn2p56CMHNdf2Q/dHRwqgaYrl8ORyUjq5dD7hl7MPDk4dB6OHpmML@wvZptyLcLSmoLr5Ctl4ZrjC3vlUlGX9bNkhN2PVCLsTIlqZVr8z4bHpS8KXxS/ePL88PnhIylyuvF2w8VRa@aThb1zvvo1CBjNZKOMnVYj02q2IlZJ1WqKtq3jCT0FVgZh39XySvptjbNvjTzyOvi8/@UfZqfbRbDroL2WoQhzCb1W07Z0Fo8M33/5@3g0w@X@Z7uPWdQzZuzv/uTHeuHv/uRf0dqj6FXFoyHSQgRColHLFyKXl8PLyyt4uF8u0ohwpLKFOJj5cLwWme8vKKcMY6uQyOr3nUpKhNUKWjziKREx6VDIRby3wktPF8HLnxUgJzmPRRDZP7JyunZ/G5lCC7Ylsfnks@mVgCuKT16@ZQws7Vqn17N0MqVSrPxOYdvvlG32DkfV3ykb7GW1hjPBGm5m8seRt2q1GkJh0VoitRVleg786leVRoLRSDT0/b4wt5yt00WOPt1gpZID7qa3JeYtTrc86OdtOfRnbnkeWH2bufXKYzLOrKRSnQ6dWbNtslwNyn8rBeicxt//8m/qev7v/uTX3jbfNj/XoedWKuU1PfJz7ec/hwBrdtH73S4aZcft7mgIumtsxWXOaht6injDd5fx8H7nDbtrqDNYPQe652iTzlHPoaJp8qOZOjEKtoWbbJOkNdPBKfGKJAXaJWnFo147STDYFh60D3VTupS@gl7QmLIqiEvpK3NQ4DCA5tNtNz17MhrSov0YxdMaSXYPokAKX8FTrzZoc7CQuQqIqdTWzagcZY@oRjoRG5ieh2doQSsifQWiiEPR8P5gA/exY0jLASGvYhDCkzw6dUi7AWnbPEKTXGOUex4gyTh2PJIDmrP0FVAGiAoW6AjM2oYAFRAsXwECQB5iArDVYNssE2eXViJRmR/QdYUrmfEQMsPfQythNITWwT3bfuQKhgMn0NjxGh7kC1HCoJ6FHH0gHAafaa2Czo/RyYZKF21yvzMogEUHysQoa@zevTlW1arViTPKEcI/s4Y4CEXl4CzHFYD5/aWPOmU5yfDos4rvGrAdUDxB6ALXKfzMs0ooKpPReiVJ8H9npkWOvFZU5FHBDIjy4rWiDSSDyEh2XoZttl1lml6IswD5NuDeJqTouK2gE3g6/UjVP/c9rwDDn0f8Q65B@pyEB/YE317fRM2g2ZvgCcN4lA4XBmLzMz8sB6XYwdiPHcSCrFg2he5aI@ig0Eyvf/JWLKPFMdr8pDLCg9Ym61mGi4RzcfxQLAzN4GvgGVMinQ06J6PtQoF6Q9ehQ6noAA1cfw0cATJKnO3D0Z44F3givSgbihzGyKNzfZDzEWM6ZIuu8qO4OHXaGkEv1qdNkpk9lbUHHaaXWIwYjc4gcgJwcYpECLdA20Uat2xzACgdmybtfvHKqVQPtKJJiw5iemIBX/UfWdCUOF5K3JqYurDOrNQJnqiruF3cJMO3tUdQkcLqx2dpxaFHtuueMds6M/l4bWzhUACPgb4PSmsSKDv/AWHLODSsZ5IsDd5JHgp@BfgUuLGYDMXdiM3iN78ZbSPWxBJ9S22SNcIbEc8NJ0Rfet5KoovrzTz/WBE6HAPsaiByTXGgQDWKe5mDkzIkcUBKlc7mUHHMfhiDDqd/sAgaQRc3zxl2ViVsY0Botv0t@liLIbdfoQaA6h7ULDxjbDwq48ESgMmoE2tD1RMC3mEfsYwuYUB@6os4oQVgYNFXF6GDH0TFfHjjDhSMyreDgVyB2jnogB9uaRbsh/F97kYznf82Z2@2IcBho0NpVRmvFr4lF7Jg7UB@pqxvgGceMFyCyUZMTgDYhByXOegg/vXonNslkiVldhNSkiEEQWqAQqqCf2UqCx0dL4HHA8PjZ1mK08guLi5UOhZvMrJU08Pj1D28BzY17FmgE7upsTkYiourLLywUMCdmxR@iwLeDrwzpXt5S/dm/CtJXa8q1lTEol0vio3jOZ4W3hvQcTp4jo1HDPXIopsG2jGxDITzn95IXvr8V0b@U4rRKwTCGIKZJmfJdhKAJVvts2T3olMRHudUIQE4lKLpO@JRlCPfMvB8kzXsBiHcMe128O0t@4ymNgGSzIdO50nzHPohZ75V2IfWFCI55gXbHY2MWYz84xgaGTg2I7WHzaDZJx8wQjPDLvm5iNa0PmssRJ8G0aFR87s8bIRn5UiX64HyQzLRf8r9p@A/5f7TeaJ@svVpg6tk6HSF2UGuxyPW/JAIZuaHueIHSs59CDIo1kzjIDDkbMHtCn7tKsX26c1tUI5VnzGAJ4ZAcDOWqn9xWj9tOJ55sdVIpHrA7DIRAkocQNcbRNOLTmBG6tvn9tD1FpwcPFkPWiWBNzq1@4IbOK9gHoMCIsbg9LLwMLTeQMzIc4VAZBggoB4Gnqga7I5jVrwSHMpKnsA4dXlOY45YXSDTIO1LeAk3UJc46Tlhw4AaIUDoHmQJ0AQf5tccfnmGLx1ejPCOcD@sQuf9D/BQnmgjCpS8VlW4rKlQIYWwUhQfTSA7qqvV61nx/aEo6te8Qtm8EuUfRn/jg9HvQr1Yjj0xLG8wKlK4quAiM1AhRHUhqrJaNVSugEFqy7DNEbRc@1w/Fa01JLOV8rsZPB3MgneBN4LGQoXfjvPyof1nsiOXA1aYVauQxVmVV0teL3yScoIH0TwRbeYzgojPBQjASC@NZopo03C0abXKBQebroh2EUJySkhOeRQeeroCyYaIBr2n4CppLJ4GaKe4pE0GeBpvRkENGsoMrwXFqelXeGAYzlKKNOcyh7hA8BCq2Mhn7cbS1OshpENC6xoAZMQbADr8Hq6ydF3gaUpgC2QUJ6Uvo7hNsAGXFcBgJIIr/FDNWMBk1AcGhV9OUDsAdVdO1CVZo3Fd/Evzn5z0Hf2fdtMxvRhSW3RMJ6/9/YM4NpCyoQoa0j60dBYFMvZknosL1Bd0jgheWdl3QatrXbgstkTZBveUf/d6qmW7rdTAwOUgeDtPcCN73O8/4JwIuz90x8bYzWbLvNNkEdstS5/3Gaye4@Kh3qHDdEHX67im50THUKhtt@dYnpnEO@C5ym7S4gR@5rcU1pOF0fUkSYxB8m4sguZ8hapus4n3BTabMVymFi8Hq2Fp1RqyZzQqYf8XTKH4IJ4E0MNhzG29Mtvj@O0w8dxnEe3Eap/FDofCMwqJ7DKQYW3Q/8G3DxoM89x5z5FOoEVVujWO0Wn/fXfg9kDrm3iqhLGvgT@Yw0aEjOGQcEkyA7u05dDp31RLYu2kERdRP/3gqOxTPWbEg/j6IoAFYiTZ6DqNkbKjJck1VybHo/npHX84vsdhfI/X40u98Os48655lXt@WNKZ2BwCBJyjkbkdDcw6yK3ODXQWUAmcUa/iEe6MYoeWW3UQ010IuiuCq13gj2Rg88AWIP7ZKvqvL0A/@v5di8/AS1SPZyBvBrgKMEZn/nv@5GYMgh/E41JkSXIBaz@8Y1oQFq/AeYQqBKixJLgcPDwTKuYQut1ecKS7D/gWnsdVUzf4npZSVbnnEpxG50l2pq8uoofNjmkbM7MTEyGTIbh@jo@gw0by6m4ZR0FHQs/lfb0YtF3xwBeacSQ6D1RewTJG8jweX81WPIgVcA@NlBOGB6vph/43RDMO8VX5aDX0A6JRPMjNObdw@HM4G874@cw2vz5DyFHe/vCSxF32txME6CCOp0nOk42vE59HsSBLd2gRgrDqYpbx@FQfIp7xcrMMP4xEt@cUCjcUqeqXsrR418DyErfWlXiIK3ye5PNGd2PJ25juzjwXYjUObC7C9j6sCbkBGddjtNuxMETusrbEXOeGTEA3GqdzVrQqzSUCNYhJkm5sUXeb9Iu4hD3jA/jigNNn8EWAPXPc5Azl5w3HtMQdKox8BsYwpLUIF1DSAUqIipzkAo1QKMk3Q/DLqyDN9so02zfSbC@kGdSAxSRDgaT2QpKiFLB41hWBbXbHK6QzemHfGT7rxDY8jmuMcLTiMmpFy1aSRc@jZRDIUTNa3o@BUI52ouWHZPCi5WMynEXLn4JhXreib6Nlv1pggBFYyXAf3YUIR3s7Wt6Lxa@ksXFmen66arQclCmE2eFWogiQAvMNWiNOsTmuyOZ4ZELDRkplkiHHeEnsPtE4TJJ@afjnt4fQLQToiWOcWxSYJZi20GiEWgyeDjQb/inXS2pyWbTm@4ePaD1TEASTSUAfLxyHwIMaHokuCiOOGPrSjAZ8AUGUm@XlGLFQS3ZHdETqwKFUyIvpE/VU0gc6MfKvQ@DGPBG6MkbE98trEQQvwLvhiZFX4XkDHT85wgjnZONL0EKivoyuyRSW9SIuovTDJURj3YuB8BZiPwgvJQIbkumgw9HkHCY2dIeLTEK@uBDeCsehQTleKZF7r0UjqSBq5gpvchY5Q8EQrvzxddkJxUPUFkQQetbTDV7LgnaBZDF6zWVdSFPllQ9QCMkcqOFm@4yu43kojBSOi5sktRWrmiE/Lk@SJNeimITIKh4XNDHGPPWg87qPhwh9WPfVjznFsZYYAgjFDFLh8tX9AP3d5fq7r1D7RLiWwDLFenlTelO9XtvKXsPcnid7swDRM8kexpcqR0EKc5JD7yCkma/jtRsqPi754Eo@TzSAfk3b98kW9Aluodv1vgWHhVrC6HzR8UwHxzN9NaFuaiT2ueorLSqmJODwjAeYzrO2Hlee8WVFjD40vm3YH1zAo8UCDhcewqMMjK6RnNfy0cShVS7zug1im7ugSNXKjAtymi4NinnuCOKepm6DaVtwOGwePTx8@vjr0OgWCoW4aKNnc/yw1uJYa9COc8i0ODpoD5Z0W/Qk3rCBk904HE83fm@cOvINWcKFNSgDBqTis5@o43Ehy0Ly/FrdhXg8bIiiAtbZvBoYC1IJVR0Dm2xL0HUMBDHHsS1DAPHVW6B3knprcbpLotnEW56bTWq@mk1cvNRsilYMi8afEY//PLKRmngjumWSX4RyIUm0z589PGQvPtk9YSef7LNHz/c@ZV8/fM5e7D49wf3az54/eHywx@C3//R4n0kLyyPx0ijsUAJdH5ptE@/2w7PWsowg77nDGZc7sb04dz82BuwTt23iNNW2Zwzu97lFdcxxjcfah@7oDMcwLboYbGCNcb0F3WoF3VhUbjq00Q7X8jMI24I@7QD7vAO3Y3UtCCth33domZ6/34vZFpQgyFt/C22SK0l4gRUtHaKr5nAF1gVENyA8zt0AGIOvv6KLtC2PRzA7KhOEC54PpuDJ/tGTY4YnAuwdPn14cHJw@PSYPTo8Auuzrx88/RjoeXB8cnTw4Dl6UcAnhw8PHh3s7ZIDRyCtMtyT/2rijdeioGJwokr7DGe@6b70wLY46o0aPLswaMuhx6ITB6WPZdjWG7MTrUgTD9UX3OZIUwUstrl79PFn0OYz8zXOcPpTwbT@QH7u0UVqm2m2TalBZalBfauI6grNnqLFaT5iMGN4r4JZoe33MTInmQ@cFvF0LJPJe7hGBce@@S59qss@aEhoA2AjKH/BSpXRfSjRaHKbQNYgtbbt4jmLPDW@iFBYMOp9f6lJRSKKibUyCBT3Kxw4OB6kVQIH4Htw0EWy4xEPwDKBAw/AstwBVdEDXDvCciLEZHw4QfHM8tzh1WD4iKaFWSFweGBQL7YocOLlRkVqsOA@KTyzwKZbb/goD93GZ3hty6IoHoXHG2Fsm1cMk99FBjKRTyXS2jYIKYOw6eJUg1j2xi/tRF/gBlwnZHTHHotV4yo7wcVBpmPx@4Z6tuHwJVDzpTvEe6yIp9JUxTJbK7inh3aADF1iQLwjbBGPIN5DoRWad40HMR/cSNEQayTprjx/CdptCDy4gcAvAgYAKQs9nTa1VLSzFMG4XcHKMc8FjsRx23fh8MDOnUnbXIggVm3FXllv3sQFkZML/SR/nSJhB0X0xhyBWklTmV13BHWcxCrdbIJSsN13h2OLl2FsMQc040TNHITGhg1Se1mtLaSGdLieouM6oURbwMUrUm0BU94lVeJ4PnceiK/5NZfA@dAI83V3iI7RwvvC53NnSZxEujBx@AUUYZorx8HP2Zgw4fqnNJcd7xjelFes1h4@OFXevUzidXlcLPAbKv1Fh/gDxsS0oHrQPB8tWByh3iVqmn/NkTdpYWyxBk9IS6zlPjDoB/Yt6Nfdb1YCP77c@KY77pG57k6Ob99WeSwFJZO4tNTrx@bSLcnqfpJJitNgYglISHYCsiDrY75LkmAG8vo@7ovBUqgARRyUI9hvv3aJkBAhfu5aky5IFnGXoyjuAH6c1WhFxfxqW9zZEi6P1BexB9VELZ6aLyhhIXLGfBGd9CFr8XhoWQq1VzfAPVwPDuT33cEV12LHm4cPgvZwLbQPwk1JrIbFm6UQrLuDfbcGLG/cfiGwkPfkasC8kbwJLeD0gDmTm5FgNe36FF/eKDuqewAG214cQQmAhlKbODRF7Z9qHOMR4mEwc4Xo@OTh/tERk3n/BOKC3MMuQ0eIQYS9wZ7NV9taDgk7NVCags5yoDz5Lgsr2vxnXWVeSrwVokLoIElBj0BY/D/FPe1WG7mSv@mnEG0S3NBu2ySQBGMSAybxLIFcDMlwDPE0dtvpO8b2uA3Yk7Dn7v7YF9j9v4@wr3Lf4f7ap7hbH5Ja3TaQOdlzJucEd7ekUqlUkkqlqlJ8iXMnnPCsJ1cWEiHI@p4mREW5JHZf1RwUNSTgO9gDArJxpxkNtOY2M8OLTxiZRuCSbi7LxqYNP1lY89qNNySOpiYg0ybI76Jnyfz@@8Ty8aaqhwUsDJKDDW6DJA3rDewT6lDxEDJ6XrIHH@gW1aVoZM8CdkbRDg2/CkkJ@8cZihiJhXCWhY1pXQrHEjWWj5eUmEMGibgM@GjpKRPZohkS1BRPX7bMDnXiRS@bXIJAyMQ7896YXAHFL@5K@hb3bLxOlrVAbo61JcKmobC8QO2shF26P9MTtIXeSE8P6apgtn2wqtz/T1W8SiRqUjSf2xiVCJA31tefPQY73QpVPPejsHkNSc@f46sh7O9jkNE0IvU@cG7t0FXpMQM8QDo2rVcDJlUQRJ05a0qi7bQYmfgBLqwXAmQwmjheQ5iu1RGTFG7zofOKZEKnLDNtMIawbiiPmhnq3z1cHU7Ij9a3@Mfr48GGmdB08A6t8t8PRlEQe@UZUVSMT@i/mvwWjEZ9ysb@TFcIJUtuTA8625G3HRu8cqswkc7bzJZ0pHcSm926StdAlZB60cObR1G7V0qr93LFktnU/dpBVaxQlL9OQhdpj2zHmHsWw/5DCNAcTHoJXD7Ih@9JtAn/AQdXgQQykTdflmjjPIobUQSk5gbd8CLNQuXcWkz3fidq@X0M6eHaTyJhu0@hIGlhq0f7zjzNeqGUKA/IRcN@Fkq5ds6zqSh8Q4UuQkqC4N7E78aChZ4aylLygfvi/XzxZWHjlUWt67tj96rx6sJdaZVtAYuv37@Krke37V@7gy83HdETw79eTlrT338TYv25eAZ1rT3lCK/FjXKewmO@gL8vxasCca5E8DVFqz23hfD4jjohlkW8Dy8tCr6fjTbNm@ghkeJSsXKluBBd7Mblq8bGRblfLpSuGv2LEjr5jVfL49XiahY/PIVVFOYYPplvjC9wTTW1rkH/RuDVpXTFnHQNEeQaAl/e@6NwcFA5fJvQxqEAgCowaetNCnW@dXQBrdnQ98TrB7dZqSZzBXKshQKStUBeQUX0aSd9Mqpj2iFgBr3igjQbTejv1LEWCt71cDygFBW@D1lLfAu/WQvKjalAGgXI0ghVkD@6bD2axHmyeDDEX6dsRZ0rsrhWRN9JxwDRwJI0Hdrnto0@hYio9OVqXFiRF/itL4gEXrP7jYqJrS26dBdYLfJIi4emHP6IHCYKF/iIByDwM6TTBqyCJPeI3D4saD6@F/GBv5COakx@MmQgb5GkiClo/i2@kn8Tld8CAjDhF1jm8qSKU0peIEiy7yApFzD8WHLjj8cM6FbJnbKAjUXYXF85Bk6W4kQjrFaSCb4v3CI5mVbwT7YgV6S3mWbo/A5nJ5LQObV8i5CW1KWUtI0/vbhY1iiWU8VUZoMUC49SAzVdsD16H8CwmordoNcDpJkWCzE58JH8e2X9q7r@qIF1XmjkOT03k55LpHuczkjFuTxY4ONMm2YmO/M1zncn7DibO1NXWZDw4kFPtzwQSeK8pYfyRt540AzjzNu6K5krdcJWIiFnpHye0/ucspgooxlcpzc4XfL3mux5jWUi75tk/fhryQ4KyHhW2pqkuNTrh73XvGjpFGQzG6gpBBfH/ia240EpfTDldAISHOr5adhul2Moq0U149CYsbe33tieFDJeZ9NosBfjzMCaM0YMKlGdq0S4CTksQj2UvGiAIJjIaEKN3G1VeCoLTw2wmGtRVctekDMDHJqWHuJl9Iv8hn/UYE8ip/Jl5icuMOYTbjx7NycJRJPuoj2fTMnZBN1F@KNs1AOrSFz3NA1x/iRxaGiBdZ0B@2B3UA2@qOcJc6JQM8UM3XWKpHScoajY974uxMQ765/5FeutDzL2sBdMRAW3GT55YVkJB/dxEI0jjO1EsWii6@Gwh6eOJPDdkgu1DBSyto7HLTFEY2X3rBpa9nB@F5@kQzoU8sQRQr5FA5E4IbrudtGZDD1gB7c4taLGJRx7VqU/ZYUGjJlna@xmHojriE9NYbffNZHgnuPRg5SOhn4r8CyQ0SKQfixuaieUNyiSPh39RjB6GCxpm5b1l@uw9evuWzzPfVEsPCsaJLuRx8EF79nz2MEKiKQS1gogxq4Xn1uWcTbc4rPhHAJ0xQEu9B@BN4OboN8PrAqsGJQxAqE1CkY3QduzrONAHwIjXGRlPJlEP@zB9ajFyh0QunxgRvQSjlw@DgMOw19cn/m4uEVnZa6Fh1bxaTN09U3YRgIqj5POAE@H6cACwwQwPbDQVTAGoqw4IokSnT1LXEh2uUJFFFAD45wYZxOaDP3BOGxBz5Amy@oBKD4GiSvrt1OYQH2tno/Owd48BNA9JqaAQkAdJT2EgyUPzf8QDkI2TJ2x@6pn8jD7DWiswHAPRiHMvjGBqVeomIE7dPDJu1pd1I/2Tz5VjqsCnj8cH32s7VX3xM4ZnXHjQTnFsRXvjg5gdtGn6XxqfgQf7EodStqUYFUOz0T15w/H1XpdHB2L2vsPBzWABuCPK4cntWrdFbXD3YPTPTp9Bwji8OhEHNTe104g28mRS7WqYlZcThzti/fV49138FrZqR3UTs6oxv3aySFWhqf6FfGhcnxS2z09qByLD6fHH47qVYENs/Zq9d2DSu19dc@D@qFOUf1YPTwR9XeVg4NUQ48@HVaPBRkJGK3cqQKWlR3YwmJN1M692nF19wQbFD/tAvEAwQNX1D9Ud2v4UP25Cs2pHJ@5Emi9@pdTyASJYq/yvvIWGmdlH6EK9Mvu6XEV4x8hJeqnO/WT2snpSVW8PTraI1rXq8cfa7vVeklYB0d1IthpveoKvIWOqgYYQC1Ih@ed03qN6FY7PIE14/QD2js40MmfgDCAZQWK7hGB0QwCWwtEOjo@Q6hIB@oAV3x6V4Xvx0hTolYFqYAWFbsnZjaoEIh4YjZTHFbfHtTeVg93q5h8hGA@1epVBzqsVscMNTTIOAPWgUpPqdXYT4AXPwKzWopzXepOUdsXlb2PNcRc5gYOqNcktxDZdt9JmnsYDddQooQD1Bn4V6ZipTP76SbA4JKzGpn5OhodMWn3aK8KK7IMVmXHCaew6rxMhVIy02Cl0YnwmghZ0w4ur7vNsN8ZoI@pLsaKj6uo6@J1Lg7eanFuPXBrhtSvUIFMptn8WGnCRrfebDru95RMoPFYCakGfyiXI9uIoflx542Kn81NpvtWglDbT@VBJxnq4QEE5mTqP2XTN/8qcEQ@3w5kMXTeR8BKdRTxsckXPEqBqZGcHfHqjbhK0kzQeyjZgQpmFXiv1UQ9KVpGUqZBBH/63@IXXhyMDzA7s7orn8dNLKER/h6oargSColAf2REgrBDVXpREPzazRbM6nDP73UHg3bWcVQZyjuGfWA36zxS/DLoporn0uUJWTp2lnHzI7XvJhFGnz9LkgnZL96IWpbFP80x/TgKG475gFpTqoqU1VJpmX3KxdEiyRUytAW6V1Ano8z3vvJz7RPu5gprz0up7@/0dx5baC@IQWhhwWtQuQv6eXfBGWCAUSwOIEkoI2Tk80YZZW@iM99Cxi@Y6TZso@UPrNVfAlrXgSQgyF77PbNOXI1H4cTEHubht8eV9zun@/swdSK2z1@uv9goWTrs1s8u/55hPRQplqKODWEdBzmNkoxRsguCD40UI5Z2zP7EwPk8ZsSY6qrT6CPGedB2G0lLJpzIsLkR3kPTRxM9O0A62IICcCxail/njkzJANlEUx1szZU/IRHfB1mJeEAas/Sm1GsT/IOw9fBXQ1w3SDKQZDGKnQucC7sLmvfsfWUqSpsbCtyDWTxb8TGHcdM0IFUX2c@idy29Sd42ejFiU0Ycr9TtVBKQWExjIZRdRZ9H9geKMyIVwBQ9DL78LPkNHs9kgDsKd@dH48q4DmTc1yVRTx0ro2WjGxLyxXYZuujpU13TlkAtvyORorEn1ck6MIgxGggVvE0EbXyTgEs6jki6SrKAfbPsiK/MqRi8A@GUJMfKd@Dcec2RUEoqfoh8V1EpBMPSQU6Yare6DktlOdNxLBQ5E2T6IXoQ/D@RJnPgb8GOE6DH1DKCAH4XJQkq0wq2r0SU8FYdNBinGzE1zU9nMZg7s2O@6IbJ05sJ@9cACWTvTNWHMwp72MnOIQAyOSo2zPGrTdK@@LB1emM7sjiek/RbV8OskGuFWipm4OY2LlwSu1x1toIvjnBY12RUeABFxRveuF3SqIctU2orL55ENoNzVPyP/AopQPSAJy79wlarac4qyFGm5gEZaslYcNo6YhKIpXf3ntqtCCNEZmLulydfilAAehvxmW0nXfYxEGyem4y4SCuxOKEoeBgPHLfJuPjIkHWXZIjZCxDOkzYpQ/A@kPEtLhA9hk6h@mJoIvuEDEWwktjqMI4ziNOt4wFpaVm91diTZhI5VGN/2udA9AFrtVQOjwN8SAxNd3lPvPengHLv@5rNLJZfqQ9ctF3EylgtIcvj3SetwWAEoqOP7QYc3XDqeOKTVDoE/eh6JOMXwnoWjqRGQgn9UA2KTbx7p2WGY8ATalE4Rm@Ftkf8QU26CtBClMOTTHIbIgvMq3h0Wykdw8lqUWS34pQtoAmFJSUibokN8e0b52KCypChAVEwjPTmgmw2qR48d9DD73Yw@hXXfhSB@u2grSOTGiBJF8idVOtTjMfWmJs@HESk0YCuQA2IpkSRFWnaUBXW6BeSnaRdkx1Hx8TYpdSSP16PZlJlLQUVxYwrawfm28hBZyKV1mRoUB0stLi2TqjM23Dd3bsZo2ihyWNrYZ/39ZSyyUJE@YkSHfGJ5039dIZPUslffhLh6IEveMYtRVBEGGVWPFednecIP7Qp@BQGo7apEwVJpu0PUf1GW59Bn3hRqQ5l2L@WP46CKewAWvlwkicYzexPgy/95u6g53fDQejDPg3DuE94xsPHKT1ih3VHg9uIrvWhhLaRqT2Nnzm@DIdhw3d9LlkyQnNF42CYNc0UxqNp5QuHiSDNORoBxvdJEn8P0zHSdJnn63EhK@l/SvZ4Rad0b9lnxXmF@UQfAcgJbjtlQcE@pGNyTDKcT0szGS4fymDgeClywnfusdhLYPwKSETHMAmMFTIzZglmI3Bndi/GjfbEbVMMwhEGWgr2ArxyJsrSZ9fHm3thFnmNlgKboviyYBTlU5QJxiHEh@n95F578SdjDwj8APrFZ/O4ZR4j0BTXUdGWIt6vyCijgAuZB4Y0R9NMDLNY2IVVqJcA2pykoSaTp/dRgyx/QCiSYfZmuBJHZBY2PnhTXLYJU05z6uCisiyWHYrbgSJIZZwt3M@wwWP2szT48RCXNWc4Me1KyFkD6ftI1QIq4SWlKfNaE2WOqfz4iFlb@95eSxGwPM/kzLiMN2sryYU8UEJeX/FYazCCydhOUU@aeixH48Fw@Tupd@/cMTcy2zxatxznUUNgZrYyLJYrbSJteYqP05KVxifFNEmKkaUZ8BBuX@lZs3maiJNyE8dbuTl9hA730Sy2m9KLiu7vNo99XBRv0KJXLTR6SBHuGKS0pL83mtDw5v0ziITJ26smzRhNnDKaU340QKXIpKn0/RQi7pO4p@jRBsphvW2gndk/9xI1bSSnQp6qpESQS6QnBm5Hp02Yl4YdNL7AMHEs4epJSgucE3dKR3nF3CUGGcYEBohScZCL9VCswY07K8VHdDtAJ9tEa6EizkTwtG1aOOig/5pgFJVfKnekxUNzmitelBjSREOCXQXlegiS8jeH10ZzQlBmSAFDfA4pdItm5qYv39@qH20L5AMIXJqSpaVvwcXGOGIVsIE/ZlJzgjJwXJUsmRhRyYHQpKkBxgLsUrq9gLerKP2FI@Z4tG6Qwwg2EPw5iz@rsgSG894oaGpjkUl7ilkcSW4ebY7IbXORmKH4HckvhyKLurRxBQABYwzly0WAgGFNCXs8FKDQOybnJRCVfQQFy0UclvCRoqLGdp5z0pGoMsPzdSNHYV6OVyaM3FwgIFjMzxMjAjLL/CwxFFjo5uJi5Hgxvz1xDhCIFe8zxaErZK8kaah7jglItxMXnHhGaRSFW5AcTInP151EouZvSn1VMFIL6VSgj8awkSumU18WEqmJatfWkkUTJYEejllrIhFI4ZgI61nhx/6Ra4oZ8lzbhBqbjISUIe2z8fZo2GXCvs37ayS2yClbyRgKnukZrrZfTb5iJRGU/eEA7GKZjgwwdvsPt1ZZpipM5F0BFJdOObtkeUNIEquNSz02C3e6KtKeDlCg9rSDjvh4sr@fCPt6OVWGRlfBaL1QKCATX5rB75VtNaqSwkE@mTvfue718sPbn0YfL/M09wcBXQmwqXbQAXQJDIrIG4y6fDME4gBZMXdOOrLiXv@60zGvYMATSuw86DbOKaMhCFqAQm308vGEFEAEUi6wv2ADsX2/CD36bn0WNCUUdQwFpdEk@MZWp2dAHvzQQftsfVJFwHBiVtZMsG455e2vuILgzSbUWRS@2Pkamyfb74Jeb@CKT3gxMEYKWLhLF9jfNwsUOAueMJJ373VE8WhdEdyEPcOvGLOYvI7g1MKk7plQceExNv5x0K1Ohlm78dmGZQWavIrNXMX41K6wu7Yjg8V/B1jmQ0D7u3Jf@cNsi@iUzgxLvRzB8RNg9Kzozt37JLI4pBOTNHs8NxJ1ProeBWuApjskC6hY9tS91JJ7smvi2ueTYgdpWGAYEieMufJ9JdDV7M@bFm/Gnc73zYp0DQB37B@aEfkmlB@bEOkMgEagHH5AT4yi/S85GNb7qYAiLODgZR2z8w4WaGIBy3rSKv92m61UKmJpuLoqKpUdeMjlRGWnIvbww86O2IP3HXx/Wl5bXy/xnLvnfIWPO@rjndgBGKThXG19Ge3BK6SV0W8MrbWxi5fy5SW3tNQsb22XonyjsoNu/fD0j3/7j3/8@3/mK/Llv/Flh14an3Umz/PyS62vS0/vSvje2LtYXrpsLA0vlrsl5LJ/UtTwQW2c82PzUW90aWV4FTC@kh2p2mdT9BlZVKhb/a780a8wu2yKTCvKZ@TXiG@Oojk20wqM7wH6UV7CFl5dOpDeygMSGQA6RXU89E4rQAM8WG@AkoAL2oFyeT5bUYp7DAejM@hTlYyMxEMy602APi1xJAX0xYUVKxf2o6CPGvAbknm5eZblw284bkr@zX9@H3V3BhOxcp4VKwWx4ooV26af4sYr@Oos5UP0zuVssB2wbRdS4qMFNDMUUUiCHu0f6K6dFLkta4mu7EFIKkwFZWYvOFfv/shZhi9ci7rWAl6aKVhFQodMWCTzdal/B93yFXLc2QlXGxIUmnIXQ5UZJyq6f1EE8iM2BIhrvmKCbA6gSjzpI49kfMqrL7KvLbpNiAAjWY/f7tO4xw@wFi31pc1zYi@F1xyR@Tx/xbWxxM7QhDamcP0xAnSgwtvJAnkSLmeWLbbyNlpJzWQvbLN9kvnY1mEajJVtOhf6V2EwAVtzm4Rb6ku/FmnIzccrwg718YpRlZ22/RaWUeTqujcOh9JdgWrHAfVV13bHIwl7lAAxHI7Zvzk7wkhRoCJFpbqFL8uaivYAm84joS9d06GDHY9Pjgwi5D9nYWx/S41tJ09eIoodmAcIKW3K1/HDXiSjroyI2F1/dIm3A/odulBtzOdmpM/Da1JTGA86GmmPIJPJeTyeoSmZ4cjvXvmuyBwOTkb@tAbLFkg@45bnQAsxBBMigYNPVj2veQphbpHsEqKIbgpZDuHlBb2pvB6N@9bWPifYpWooyLArOAgS7ESUDL4l@ipFx5ir/0AnmCjPTN76NFJOsTTzoqWRhGSbbjM0zGaGjqVqMMeOHji2xajqkal4QRa6xoX2ig5@YSbvYYwAWbctvQClK8LGK6wfV6du0PcTi9OwZylH/3xJ8LqI45muomRrJEvdfFqMb7xDrECO/JyMAsFrkwpnZC1kswvnkbzOLWOuIxTkW9vi530R6gvo6AIz8gwRp/2QJ8vUChXfgeGJGln@A4ROz@8CftNbf4qseJ7Jvl7MO43P5/2Llex5/9v57w5hIqdktcrmREYeZqsZS44VWBnzbuJVWaVFKtTgeT@Z4bwv2IfFIAEgks82PucvvuUBofMM3il/nmGCJLoMMck/XF8ewedn0MwkschnrAVnxVGdn31ddASsrfSLfcgfHP4FLNSmktT0sM8ZdQAU@en@ds0uJ1H@5Vrh@VrxOeyEusEkNwqucb3NRdeXwQREiQi3s7D0nP@e4IYEIe4mkV@CjxNoJ19rwr4nkXRSklOoHOZUj6XZCsp4zBOQH6hM4VLRxcXReXw8fMQNvyuA5VReigXFpoMG92Vx/YwGV1iPH@G8lvYOYY5EKwO2ESEVag4hq8tX7uNQRw2XZfJz8sQuxm4lINC9@YyxWvQH/ZwU1hxvuYRCNHrN9F4WXhbSY3RmiCZG6JIUppYXRXH79Yu//9fRb5lxZnst/2kEv@PMb5mNlxl@hAd4e6bebjLbmS3MtnGXmeZhDwyPL/7@P1B@@yeAgynTLfizva5gbUwz27kyFfmW2d6Ah@LaGtT7v3/7G7RhiXdseBfrUtMVhFhJUWTX7xPvQrqoYSt5W7ocTyvkmIUw2MIQ9ubwgoZRk7WXBVLTZaRVxU0gI18pexS5xJNh1phMhViToewpQDLiAmWsIMcglQlFRxi2G8psA5k3RlP88sTbiGAH8Is059BVatONJxGaDC3xtgg6MMs1wn6eH7YLr21t3rFpK5uSkhIhcWsn59qXz0r/Bw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2tmxk)

IE9 is separated from IE11 with `document.clear`.
`IE=99` is a golf of `IE=Edge`.

Answer (score 3):

## 324. [Befunk](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunk), 14700 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1 1 v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v   >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9 @,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMn>MnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001 1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::geEx Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0k:4o $/op>asequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8 4?4920C05r""Hadisptext在ｕR 8
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4UE8CLDZbPI2dbubLZJ9@0ogGl0ACkA1gSp0FUACzWaHpNnVWrZ31qORHfJjfGXNelZeT8R4J3bW8o49E2HvxwnHfPIPaD82Nhwb1j/QnnMyq1AgAZAtjyM2NrZIVOXz5MmTJ0@efDcNr/ezn0XwYc@c/rTbd0ZsZHoj1natc9NV2YMpu29YXk7PSBKG2nG744Fpj7ySFGEaY97IcEesb9jdsdE1WQRcdTazd6z@yHSTzDNN1jT7zgX4ZxizzQt2YLesNkBiI@fMtK23pgt@WcYemv13g3cj1nIGA8Nue2zoWvaIfHOMPTPA0hm3zpjR9Eau0RpZjg1eecae231j0GwbjIIPXZNH2mQAqnVGceZ9Cow9cVzPhBSclul5DjoWwdFwLefxztNPr4XX0uxTA5Aa9s3JteQ1jb2wTLd9PYbOPj/Z37/ummGfKY7N9m@ipGXZznjkHIyuw8@xna5pG0xXi6p@3TMPxByZ/UK6kJ7zAr99y4XSNESplWYlY48HTdMF4osivLBGPRUinDic4Myx@1NmTgAY4NiBYOaIWVhaLJdOY0j4PzZbjt2egQcnE@AAXHMwHE2ZwmxH8AB4OS7zhkbLVNpm3xpYI7PN@hZg53QENh6DAmdn5vTCcaHgFc6KhIg3NFtWx8IoIgeehMz20GyOu8wZj4ZjQM9jbcszmn0I1pyyttkxxv1RkjXBD4hH7hc90xYoWXYX8/Fi5oIQbKgCHPt1DWhj9fsM0DlDdDBpj22hxwW6Y9CmSViabQS1NyMXQDL6np/7@YTnksF4z1yn6xoDYNS2STT4/OAZ81qOCzb4YVheC1aBaRkjtrXFontPH0ZZNSCj6jalgKQVdskYi/ie7Nzoj02PDYwppG2PoHIxh8rPjyFBcBZdi5ZYNJNhepplsywLla3A9FyaQZUoggFqrZ7R4JdneoFlNeD7XDSJ6XRco2v1TQ6l6/Q7CGgTOVbPMR3e6SzLaIVokodoUTqbLFNg@U22mWOb8C6yog4JIdQs04o5@OXhB1CKgIUGv0yWpxawBrIUZIPtso4xsPpTDn04RPAtltPYJkAEVDWArBcAQlFHCPNPGN6oB8TtGecAUulbZygyzEBqYIml4JPa2EiR2EL5yJP0ema/j6kCsYBMuQLbhFTzkPEspAy01Au6n/luj7JPeG2m4Qc4bkKOC0DiNFArjeTahB/YQRTpIHN0EDA6yAxdA3cdzBmECuHy4JeH8spnfeh6m2gLEhbiakhMFCoa0gCiQSGwDBRFnmWhiDNYxLkMAzwBgc08A7lS0FghywqbDMhVTDMgvQbIYPlrIM80QEJDYFCsGpSrBohowDAaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFctDz@IB4UvAZJapCmrhdn7AW46TnIZC5DfKfnofA2wQ@IpQOuOnCLDtjqBfDHuAUgXAHZctMnhNEf9gykBZQAMjOwGhAkBzgRbAgPZn0zw1mKQjfNkdWSriSoWbwVDEsdX4KgFACJwgyGjSgw4Ix7YoEUjINQmhdYY8/sAxeBHGkZYEa2hRqP0sOHY41UlLXQVJnOOTamJALmkvFITDRdbElBZrVN12UYFhpcL0kCxRs3PfPNGNvbGV4dkFAmCNeOYfUDBKjqGCNqC@Ab9SC96TzaHdcZUP0aoMDoO85wiegF8XSBgB45F@YM9Zn0MobDPsh0cDeBEGOjD8hcGKQTkMoQTpUjBJEwXqtnAUBKCmSr5Zotor3IOsTOgBSeR7HE9Oq9DEJ5EGoaMmzogGD1MI497vdL0OSZLZapptrmeQpdePMx32wgDn6DAm2iANE0oD2nBhWxCCDd01Vqqk78kvWcwXzWuHg5CLLes7AZ6F8YUyi9DkgWc2IMQOtg2LTb0HgPgGN4CWJJeLzxOWBtx46OAigXLjSxkOkgJwCyTzQZWQMTdDIHomCJZwlpFG6EWXMKrEzUyqqkknFMrhFKla4TijtkQw68skDj1h63kGqYtmUTB0Gj4FGLVQW4XPFU0QBVzjWNNg@GGgZiFNKRoMUzgehCHWgRINRSTNsDjcdTmYWqITB81@kAj1EzDeoGRJ2l06K8Y84Dp4naUiWiNPLN4KzPLNYaDhm4g44CaO2nC9DOOq8t9hY8@z2P9Vtj152yyRAKwBpAqFHL6XSAad@awx6AYIM2a01bUCshl8g0UtshCdQaXstyYFs3IYxtQrZ3n32ddU2gNrTKHcCUOH2WgeGQskCkMGzeYtsGUAqz0BpOiSwAJojRcRwV3duO6RGPgEYT1HhMzDO7VCOgenVmMmiAGggwJ2gFNrAsCBxRqxA@JigtzAwmJQr/U9OGGtMCZoS6DsWHOukO64D@H2qsUcEzWi1zOBLs4ZAUs@yQUnO4j0oNuSoCmOr1pPX7oI/NYSBBUMnnnFALbpyRcEVln3QtA0Ws6GRAm26bgRrLuEDpT28kDyHOr6Uuv8Iwcxi8kpfgMKSagBoeyYbxCCUICkWr1UMROEIhQ1oGVDJ3fDP74BZO3h0wpROkjdhoIG0kNRU4IR7LYSjw698EpA77CKs654BB5xxuAW14gwWQnQDJfjvsqqYMFWThbUAHju0sgArEDOBikHkfKgtixmOUGkY/YEaqLt5cGaGcnvV/sf2CpnM4dFyoGVzoTFGS8SILcZfD@yqxoImIQ995vkWFliKK7fxoxPtdwz70haiKYU0FfdIASQFCjPcCQOY5PMUQwlTrCZbA74IkPmcmaEJt20SV1HCnHAhkD1plSGjKLNcFMXiObQNvevw2RCU@habAaLdRsiI5qN5fT1xFjt4dN63J9a5GCx3V1550brisg70MF3QNqESxaMeLxsvkTjFDXnLKGY5SFJW/ZQhIgVQo8lgHOi7QEOyDoDme2q2YPFfF5CSTx6NOQY6DASNy1Yx91RiOrmP3GtyQaQZnUK/JVmZdaLUVBd4KuhEm6JFS0cNwQb2ASghadrHYbhrsHUgPlymTXYqNaiF9NTUbpGXa7SAtQQjEJZxflSfhuS0yKKFWDXOAwSnn1EjMEfCOlKCIMjikUqL9RAdS8rgfqTPccWzTEAGLcQ0kzi4DFR0agBghY4HOYbWsUUNoKffu@frKWqUCzAZKFIjNdjys3PtjKSpIagiskhIiElFHzvEI60YsDvnFwFccG9CWgFMrVXY56rlQ48h@JUEgIKtkIyf7hBXl/NQ6G7evF7SNjhhIxloHupLVGsllCRp/Xhsqq6ganaMqKP9RpCoyL8Yn0DeYl1yxQGURzDU91HorApVQCccQA8GrC0nEowq3GUPvTlt9oRJwE1R2Lo2agP6Z6K0HgigpdAK/0t6oqRwIVgcOhz3bOXlUEXWRe6aall2ac@g7LaNPzusYXPbjPj54cLRz9PXGAhh9q1m67pCysoU8NrXjidK1x6msqpfWwzBmgB82VsPGiPNhZEl4M8WZhFSlaQsal4lPzsOjz66TBDQhJAelAGb8XVNpeBhQuqSm4fWuNcKsm0hAkkEUPyxTDpgPMzAg6uhv@Pg8G799i4V3HamhcEfM@mODA/AdUwe2H09Fz2sKmO/V7PAWkeKCFmrZOAY6M4VD@vh8ilrzdWRIlQ6xzKeH@3tHFQLbM7wzs99XKEjKG4EuZbhtFXi@P26b0qIwIP7A1GIJdYY46tOE60ICt1pzBJ6VLVsCHwBgF0d1mNIf@FnzeoD77vW8kavSCjiA7AThul4Z1odaH4toCA9s4lrY013UipLHrLEKnBa2WIHvfLPVyuXMzWwx3Gy1Zmm2w0AHpBRbjq83uuB15inoos60SKFWC/SPH99A3CMlEroCio@Z12cqpeX1Jey9KBaLeqld6KE5fVN9QRJPZnI8lYr6g59qy6M@Zyj83sQaxdJx/tXiEBZS39k50B/6gcVAHQ1gUKcBu@DYMrkdnGxoecAjttN3ug7bgDhcO/QTBLVpaTZ3uo59o4QMdMSsRnD2AuQvjtcYQ2hrrLfUcaRY4e4qn/kwbO8CpLSWzyCRiEIEKkXh1dfGuQHkmuX7@OAbe9CIaLl0OjCn6QEShOIQudDUCrmSA1MgIVXgszCDwUzGjdrueyihqQTMtBB0QcSdmfdCR5KYamph@IUofdW5QfHXzvQaa4ELZy0whEh28PTZ44One092vjgd6bncnD2bLuaBcJBeE3QhtcfphrV1g1dNzBaCi0DdcLF6gRQYQwfFHxIfey4IbhWDqByBJVzD54BiX3V6dtSLX8/MBfoqr@0WZ6EnWPl4UBEROtrtPnZGXD51hu058k9vNBp6pVQKanlv3FSh05p63XL6RjdF8aBh6PdTGnZdDg5xXMNbFAOQ8aYmj8HHtEB1mNLAodEfONB5oek4FA0sxsHTYFXf6vagL4xzdqYbVwMOptyk2tBDgL5yKsgbCWCyAW3F1y8nmbP2VzS9wPlaS@vZlOwHm6v@EHatY0LXKQatFZAifs3KTu@d3mNTkNII6TqQCFM3xLQNtgV9BookDZZiP98nDkkLHCZFWUE0ejPGQVyQUqlcOrup5XMp6JZBNw10VgWH2pSBMWr1lJGjADzF6dC4QYgLO17LsDvqhjD4yILe9wlkNVN7eXpq10FBP71HuOFkWG1ar2n1eJndjLIhwsfLwL1z2UPe9R2Ad8kIrElftkSetY2b4qxtUO1qs9RoMBRtjjJkT3ZAkXrrgLxum@G6hxFSYc/UxlzYFAZ@n1owINTHqBK@kFIpqFDQ0gLrpRAvBZReVA@Bc0BuhSKw2WgGzwefgg7JEex0I99bTtSjsXrUa3CQ1BsCEWmMuYVS2sPxwRG0jgHno5SGwkUhzS7MKA6fGx4fpIRIYuLRjw99tQACDcYHA9F2MOEKTECxqHsOkgP4CkdLe7NRRuz0A6dBgoQTDj6ABmHTpEEX5AxE5hnZ4RnhKZHLfJbObOfCRmhNkxWUpjXiY/zO2MUJPasdzhsEz@g8DECjzIXkOs38Nc0WH2XlkSkX0Ak02MAcODiUANoViQKTsmDwWUPsC3o4UA3VKq3gxAnAV9j9XZBiLZOPFykD7EQBS@2x6MhN7SjfSBnKW@DmFboVZn4nPIlNhX7iE4BGIoNZbBolESOgpJ04Awr0gsZb0POBr@5Kw@moBzkGDpONijM07et9Pt4jjMXLNNcajYLAt@zYZXRtbS1ailajSTBtg2kLTdtoSoBpm0wKmTCciiaKkSQT@tYoBrrVo1c1H/IkXkcemKDm8NYaxoxaqZSpJ42aJr46fuNQFEB5CK3gB@BE45UKGuNxuXqBUzWgv4fyvou8c9xyraEgwVdBIeB2QYMMEQG696jNu2YZ@6arKTKouNBpNFHFjLnR01r6tH56edpOnF5Fkxg7XjYq0D8E4TWKDdSu64yHoLjVsiUFZFu8linVy81KNB3diMUKSh8SMuLxTwrxhMFpHYuawFOx09MokFRQp9bquQRvktTj8YBQgEfHgl5Gvx@LqpcFSL8Zr8cTUYgbjyZBLFeiUaBLC4ngUaZxRIAz0b41AVJCxYQmLjynQAKS5qSwun7DHPambjhAMOoGWjaOoM8m5KEykBQPS8m3PH5YoZvr6ft6Lw8Hyi0O3qG@NJxy6S5xTE9Tc4tD/Hb3XOkMnJGR@lyFTpMaai6ja9GUokBLSD4cEmX7ieVhFTZs0xl74ZHGhQOgmDq4nvTGICz9lTNJ4CprKJmtnsOi6/cBOgumebApwRkrhc97@QDaLRV@KERRK8HJEtAuaEmJBXIRl5vwURmNkOCixx@bz@WHb9QgtTLFYWlMyOrajmsqQBKIIdECEFouJFWZWFVyQCNfN@YlhC81adjxtkyQiPt9xyDacnEdmg8aDkLxoX8OUY7MttQH@dEB8ajysnDNdmpDoslZx@1BCwG5QUmsB6U1EB4pxxu21dEEokoxbHDDnrx3B0rnBWvrup5v5Tol3w@5Aojdg0LCXqkNXVzfS9HAMy4KeY8PC/l99KeHD/f42Ak1tti84jhaY@C0x6BXin7TkWl3k2wP@MmynYEFZPDjvz3rHznOiPfywbJsZIZ3mq3BuG/QmM/1YZmV8VpO0@nTUNCqqLPwY9cz@gYfhPJ9dz5/Arr@85PjiloKBUoZ54OVaeM45OJkOT0PwnOONM3qTw95nDHl9ZyM7Za/IA3FjPDIo8dYLEeDMvLdN9Hdr1I4hyLcC@g@wKVooCuLUQSyBo4iYJEC4vI0XNUjHC@19BW6L@2DBeE0CscVxxm2l5pO7uejTmfOOUPOZwqKpv7MOUvOfJnaXB8xjFKOB8I1a3NhwoDyFCZYunY9nBBewRKDntn3ZxCPQDHBWTJo2/uoPkHfBDVxvn7MBEV6iJMhJKFxio21QNf0bgxbQJ0aKjy0FFmjegJtWAo1F2k9xcQQd5lqiu2IqUmPS08HuvY0erJV5RPW2HVyea8txQff1xsAYqta9lcTLQuGKUWjQTCCSrhBDMomTdvfyGqwCMOjMXWJopQlLwW9homeVk4nm3v1lEdE6DD59HTySVr/AjofuO5r/V6qa5YxuaXUIjsfh271QGywxGSeZFAOY7vj9NsKn/SC8me8u4QFIZYaBCvPSOCDi@X6i84sXMQiFgeCuAytV7sB91rRVW8GCK1wCwBBbbhk786S5@9YDVqwc9Ub9q1RnV2pI6fRw8yPxq59fS0cVyld15h6klipUmE7R59@XkvXOQRpYOBEVoGX1sRfSgl6MOg9uGIVTLjeZmSNqGGnhQUW5ldTAakJzXkA@gCDJ1BmQUIiR4j6O/PdLC8dEzqeMRMx96aDJDPjV2qnb4xGps15i88mLic3n/YRyVQo@W0xh1BiaZpoAUXTQj9AscyOTx7uHR2pwKFeLLqHEzIlqHZGqwf6xrJM@5QMZ77EPmlH2ScYJ469cAmqFHQmGiI@MG8ZmBu6E5A6ioKu6cbAMY5zKS1wpukrisgVLkEgXDXVGhGNAmAxMw55ImClhfg/t3nPSeBZYlGWIEoCuWP3SkBbK66ObeuN6kG7QWooBInyvictk62sx0h8rWtx4h/XGuBcMHSZSAuEPNRqbA2kG4WWWeU9e1lLK8V6Yp3V62U@ww8RUaenZbdiCach6Mmnw0hACpwPRK@sc20hr58CjdxiLI6fBjwrCb4FZN1xc3qzlsrruhwPkFXeggP3lK8juWChKUfRX9pEIoRWQs2vaJpfLxXK1nPqZF9bIA7Z8REI8oPTkDGeS7ZWYVo87mPGAb0wXOw6l9gzx/OsZp9WsHb6Fl8JFjTWJUEYAcmnTDi5MlYMohvWZ6hnWBizZct8MbCgBPlTQwM9KcwZOcTi7BKJSaTUkYrs3Tt0kNm6zogNZFw1zOl75fdpQT4@dgDZx2IVdFjnIKEhlqeg6DiVZL/zNj//iz68Y5A6v6bzKudyOB7XOS37zKFZpMDUSKtaDvXMIPbgrH8zZsfyevSaCxrgwMPqy7DzBs0OvRYEoMkUMU1PDjRMLzRsKE4jdUQfGrFfkPL80pS5ZJtmZ2x3aU4TzUx5c0tIpVigwJ1m01oWFIiAq83874JgICux5ulqVtX82oMDPNAsgvzkfaJZ1q@vamJzdIdGagSxxPc/f7MN9L9ZOj1or3A8MzA0QFPAklI6SwtLREULvRYXLB92H/ctgwhDpttAtgwXsmT0A8Ni0DS1ryigbwxwokKUOPAmvkAXXcFmHHM@z@h/FyeyaKrOBrndWhb22iovnhRNKkF3sU1E4DqXZVIkErK8EMwJn9gJddxR4N6OlL8UixEz83LvjUdj/gZ1@NZCtIb4W1U3Rch0zmhqJnRIjaZlrihy1zgbtx1leNYN1OL8grCz3NPMsgJaiZhkbqBxcfZ5Bl2rC829/10WbNa@pi7ocxtXePbYGypN6tu3uY0qwmBFCm6fv5cFscRupcCwnGpWn1535EQBHRhFrLFI4QpWJUQ06xqZ@0ZziqpQ7@O5LFivABKn0kok0pklE9bD4fL42D@l@MXi4tgTtcXpsWjkIcVXySp8bI4yLNbN3lKq0FxZA6Ov6O2QcakwX7Tc4UbQYKaU4pjnOE90vrDkZtTHBqk17hvuzLSCxWd4@JMTy8a5RbMh6nLL6VseVuj@Mqnpr7mbpYXrlOkVWldhLaJkGzqi2I4rgWmxFHBaI1yLuoSt7iDT@BpQXGkb4hPVWUaslnOBv6UaRA86w/y9uFF7uxCrO8gnpd/qG9CUL20R5kYdcVTzFl69sDyTXosJe7YQ0VGrv9B9vhb444nh8cHbONuz@o7Hjum9ikBdF6jA34t5OkxLy7AVGmUPm1eIIX/xxKxAjX7X6ecL3ZQBr6WlPnY7KPrF965CLhBSmnaLkPI1IMfWxHepaD9LuWe3FRDt/3Jx4WzIuKKVXSSpxKTO8txB3wBnBBfnbD9doJhqio8hLkkY53IujKn//Tlaj2Wk9VuP4ZQ0alDwMEKxAIaRy7Xsnye17OrU2ncTSjfAbt6WiVDhnvVNaK/ofaNImZ7WPjKGlk7fXUR1@mNzbC7saxw2X5u4lXhFP@PuSKVFNtbFFADOOuCelyDUW9E5vBPW2FSjbaUwMaDXbt6uzcwLtSEo4EPsPT8DwzM03IzRtcfDuVKd66DZR6tJ1hv6Vdppz2GHPh8rhwq3KEtzKrpn0m9lp4l38nDlWSWbTqeFDhOaypmzrOpMZYK4ry3@nkuYXGYpz8Li9J0bMi5Og8gSXtu4VATpy/r2FLhYTNmWbY6m@L6jNG06Tv9jSgqEattCbQyUS1rDu6rEbqg7YncKm41eeDjm0ewsG7fgrY3oXgJ9sN@8qtDDc013Kk0FZ1MHONM1b109ghOaubotFdzSjcNCfFVvf7kuKQZENLWgbq6sdVxDdZpm3@CfST67Cl5RzayENy80xCwwzhrzueLZHH/kmlAaToFYVhs6Kj1zYJJ1haJvtF@PPf@zNNDEwd8y74lptlKTPbO1LMDQArlg43tucjqkLI0cG7pYI1xAiF2VPi5RFa7LJLA/nbiQyAcDo2vycypWScrZmAUu0@E9u5lx8ehFiS/NaUG02QjzcpaASnVmTj3/uxDgk2kLynU8uH3E7Vrlb@Ew6B1q@7K1sTebWLvn9Oye2eML0gPbssoB/Dji54qsQh2w7vZwjdxwOLd2PkzPvtPv34WeKBq5oHSczkKc9nBXLW4J@yi4U6MJHuJz6/idMeKyAw1La03PHEO75DkjZ2gqZFsWtI9jPfy9TIb6s98/7yDSyq4@UMT//rzwb@1bdg1nNBzSpzHsjz16UVSFNkPfpjd1@JoXWm3puF31rTNoqsJRFQtiaNJ9sYhpWqNWDzehc842u06z1bNuQ7ppGiPbOkv5oz7ceqe@K1LGYspDdFb7FpDXnarIL5Ww/zF@DpYVuhhA4s1aYFihrywapKP93srQOGt5fEAUTayEY8Kh2sh3hZdoO33pzdgazYCGFkkFI7x8ZgINy3AXyzKWala0@WImhsVyjaVcSko6KuSKmQaFR1s6vjS3gC5UxTIZ/lqGUDiXhFFowcvHkFssKqIBQis0dAvuc/w1txpqYSNn98Zd76bA5CP2bVDR8LV82IIWSYdGraHNMmzxWUZmvZ/C3ZPwbYDONTZXTqvkVs6rUDitrxiOBZ8GfKDoxkvH0PrW0ONvpnSWzsaJRVLQF78@ZchpM13cmRYF0zY7fBYETbepiAOH5mlBB1FaOKePg@gozLnixQWX7XRBqCt9Ngvsh12mtixcf7S4@IM2U/niqdk1cBH3Y2uEq0AXcAWx7KJ1S7fC/trY8KyvjSFny5gNj4LgM5Fu@MwAtC2A98ToWq1HcwURICkILJaQ8s8c@6PTzbK46FkerqEKDCsGppDlOBMj1zWg37Ag5PWh@@AUjFkF4vsrF4ZeNLzuDKe4DW1KplUj69aIRlnFd1nXcdnqspVIXIwHw7EnPotxoFVa4VHowRm5excWAFfegGhlPaM/WjxSHRpyBS1MNIoz4zJt/BtW3@mybxTSDJQ2UMJQOV/AOA@geX6GS4NcewEnUtp3nPnEgQ7F5Rl7A2VrZphi2dZo9WjOaITLhPwvZoa3HLj1IfUY3@r9j4WgnCymyOPbdf3Znudb2nfgvGNn7LZMNAYHmYS7BSJVc9df1oxbRRw8iOUi3EtbOXsDzaFjj0eKO7ZXtgr5la1CiU0K@RAbsNjX9p48j4e5gZaB36aFmtD5G3v96cy0dM3ANSazbFDElsvR@dB@X@IhP3fpiNYg3xJnBw@HapG4fugs6u88m7rm6M4dJhD@48FDs4Uzh7em/dR54tgOtEZDEJSDI5MfJjC31mNxRIz2GLfLA33atyZzTGCXNEJc2zCGZhPKtz8z3aUt4oAfGiNjSVNEY4PU/wtMt/KK1W@a7msa9AuZl3Vp5xF6ZE6ob7GcYXgdVEatFleJcTxuro7Mzdh4Q8ex@ZukbRo@2pPVUgWaAnrdfa5cxRX@c@MCC/tn81k9POcLRcw2P@1iWV5ds@n0@XvFsiTb4ssCDNcyvdRjPDyB3PJZpoD25a2UIZsrZcisawSa7Lnh0Tz94q7GDKQ2@YhVQD3DbTk4EyYMKxbohE48uEVMB5sG@NqBJhB@AhLLaI3F2Yu3odUfNAf0WtphCJXmkdnE7UZNOiZkZExuFiYfGRJnJIQWdQUnC/jiCit1nsWeQW8kfnuzNdePmqeqNaQXSeql0@W0XkexLbP11sBRM4foNRubnvOHPKeeknHJWHWoGtEocsqgLfQLa9L86jVQaPqmMuq50OdPjVYNb/vntyyYDxkPTJxknp@FWaq6Ol6PMussnk8PhKtrKuLsQJAlwTmCXD9UdpZqngge/g8ffDUFjXAjn/XPNAHRdfsMPiA/dm3xuQsHPnO8UceaHALeuO9gmTjBbOUgCnx4zUDTxrJMQOnZ4z4ffeiGll4N2tQdU@gMW0Xpk7gemYppnyt0wtzkZo4cvpsstYOHoY7MtiIOWMCZBuWxv7EsCCa@CyZQw7IR13tqKU7YST4rVoAuIu6FLxlA33JGytCjb2roPTt4fHiiDj1tYfu008P9GDf0uLkTG/RCOjQk9dpwQ/OdfEVa2/JGqQfHmrL7@EDFAEvozWc0FPjgzNzcZ@m4pzh61EgZS3tB6GuOFiuIj06ePE7M9n6y2G7PdQZmPOy9e3ycxL0tXz1e6B2OvQ@1o@NMlkY/2NO0@AL2fW7T7OAy6bkgpWWQTkzojQIzPuIHvtyqXLWcodk@mQ7Nz6HxRAnu3TH5/NJMPjXOrS7WQlZcSiiqqKyo5rPx0OJs6GybbvBdVp5n1hClZYs@Kf5ZuhwFNYdMys0s1h5Wzfhf12JYWqxE@LhIWvomt44sBWpGt4emlOH9QxHTNG0ZnY@NDpQryy0trPkAi@aH@875HaaSTdF5UQInZQRcpVi3LiXfVAYgulP4wuF54QjG5tJlMKsABM75hRX@wrSnhq3QXNYq9aIEsXFR28og3zDvMCEVrPA5xwOhF87xBavqWaxFxvgtCZ@4oSi7uw8ObotwJGi5OtSnT5@zZ4aHp5usDhjG2LwDxjPN6LWC41Z4tN7S6dS2C6D0lfC6w8X1ucSODbft2NPJ7ZNwtLkVm3Y6rDiAhTYKZPatibWorWrxca1ni5cZ3ZY238fhTOf04PCpNwLQh@/8c01Lp@lMI/xqaW69pWT8Cs5iaDKmeFBe2OvkIBANLdRbVHCIL@yNPjYnuByFjwYv6tQvbN/yK9q@zfjy5mSVX2GFX3ZFejf80JFl1LS2AmBuhR/LqYH3Y6d/0XPUXcM1vTuWSQi1VVkqrshSMSSn3xbSOBxKU4zCvFzZx30M4rOQb0/MkZsd9pymlb0lNzsdPNGSPcED2W@tZLihjBa/dB2xJ4TbF@NwMb5NQj0x3pp3kU0r12LwnWVHYzt81rGXFKdV8A2hfIuep/oHUsdidiIRj8/feRDekMi34uGJeHwXHYR9946tic1y4BHsHxRb9PDgLNDcTdzYKhEI3DkZsysVLVdk23jzQAna5TiliE50PJGfVo2tX4qdb6WSdoW7/@SSzMTOxOC0UX5iJsDFs/4gT0w509j6CHzW/X1zjM58Z@8Y6fqgXGi5NNjUVHgjc1lsKASU1i@fHTzbOz7ZOXl@XEvXr@S42DbLcbNtSM3fUP1Jpi1D3gXZQIbw83Np420fkqPz6LGP4Pn5YpCza1mrzGVtlil5G@OsX9p2KkX7R1PKFeCnyDw18gWFAJ04bD/HVD5i@2@Jb7vsE0nldQ5apjShzEosvSjhoQG8v24L/@s3YpAvy2TQlycsjjwFluw6Tluk6Jns9sdPcX/n4PHzoz3mIzhjmgurPepVijl@Ii62s4oJ5dSxaClKhUVFlCiUVaUS3Y8CYaJqlJVo1y6dRgt8DsF86uB@XxF7g8XWCT5QMBoUSuo/fzN1FVVxVWUcwkZ9pKJMUB4DsBPciffnP27z09r98zf8q1/cATUqdM6BJHbZLtljixSlijlcfgEMnY5O22mDY9lnl@pIdFg/cOUFHZ117VilOJ10wm/zEade@QkRg/gnPOPwHJ5g5Xrs3MK9tByHDh4oNc/KOKNPh6ipbAdvtwGeZwbdGACoj@0RP7RFHPEQAT5SA4GSZOuELL9fQA4FjG6tASs3za5lM8@GPo85KrHXwGc4BFbiG7oVpRq9EcUHza81UnqjQT8U8MYJVF7qdJT68KvfTXXLDMyT9AOw/bKwdcD8K9z8MoVlffOUqln6YSTwZDmBNU88oDnSO3SRj803zs@IhYdp@ZKSWQMomnOiNAbnKfC3AgJ2BidW@xwKClgMSklsmOfpmW49hkfblVIpZCNsM1VaJGxO@Iqda0fc5XP5rJYCJJVzHyCdSd3F3YgcYDxeAsaXzq1h5VUT2Gtri8moQpuVfJmXZmrdfpmRXwWIrkNY6aKHyNUYxIEosxjgVxXRoDlJaHGMivIoqkVRFLUdaGfIH9sjtNuCEDKLAbE4jUw85HiCNzqN3Kl/VGMTb0kK3VewLgApGrQyZIrLktjj/dQZAcvM7W7ne7xxxRpv0/AMNI/fWEYnJCIPqjdr02xron8xgqhfKtZ7DiqTvt48hstWfoEgjhFESV7EsrWX7HR0atdTnDcZsOkPBcuGmdkG8y@lukt4lud75@b5eLHrp9shsdj9Y9vBvsI@ZIbF9JSeSWn5@CxL2ezCLIkciWQgO3hqxztIDkQTiImWab12ht7O7t7BVw@fHd84A45CRq8HA0le3UqcKmqyVg8M0XC25ovkwX7q@MmDfb8gZkjnQxIYtBeRE21VTmZDAAhytqT8etYWYXg9d8sxfsH3nV7HN6OvQo0i3cBDS39EurSsU9mnzRnXE9cLi6iVy61CaQYvFQK9y3fW3UA1Fr@8qtW3qqd2JHqTExZUhJcRdQMrAZhOvY31FDL7zcxhxoKbBU/wPiQvXBczi@uivJ7Bo4hwb@/IOZsdwiQcQh6h/PrJgIiU1JQfdGntO@Ra9@yoMJ3ffMgPLQof1RJCOJ9eRfEQqBP/EkWUIrODDsUZfz3oiPetpuQfkcPP@vOPJAuO@ePH28TikjgunyccE9cqTkoTldZwxOIo7QhWkq06NtCHF5egQqO@9mwM3aNnzpAfn0xzdQ9N33TkgPh9OOaT/ib76ngA4Tr0OTJp3BQktwKRgZLRAFWuP4GUEKcGThJ4LiOkV8OzA0XG1UE7F5vE1Z45aVtdkO2xeBIk2ieaVmfByYKYaTpJ0I7KVGazUlhZFT/F/ZJhsn/U8ZKTGQJGzVAtu21OYtGLaLxUh/TRPXrx4jwalxfxEh1zKc59bF8/7zJAf1NbLUmMkaid/mGSi6RFsXhTSoDbdcD8oCb/7pZiUe15El3BVUFd/HjkPgYjqBGxzsAYstjY5odZqYyssdOYnaTTf5QqPw/PZokEdZHgQx4qo5gdMvH2O2bYUxZLVYAJ0NWz2/h5aw1ZTVPVOpgpkThbxzuVdkHjwoNh4hL0aiFKicBWkIWg4wAY8UqicgaHOOgv4Xk9Lh0JtsCbrpih4SUHaUK5ZtV7LHQ11rzmKBeLJVGg81KxyID7bopDNQVgb8g5X5cH6oqDJ4Bm0KFVpchMkN@UeBFKN8IReSROrAB0IqEzLP2DLBjAmp0w2eq5@Ivt2VBX8Oyd0vOT/UYhnpJZcPJF17XaOPzJj2EOOm3i4gyopqm5oNEy76N9itHwSLMGP1oDT9zapwojXxOpkTAZrl8WO@NNTVvJ9SKiKAUImcUGQGwPavjg8Ow@fyJ6gd9iYf@zn@F1tHJsfTufafTPE9FcugwvrZxjOfbJ@qmirNc0LZuu3F83jNGbU5kZqezGw3Oz12kedFOnsswyLJtKbUT3N55Zev7lm8lVRiu8ORtq@Zr6ZlKXC5XkWX3Cnj374n3jfVyenE/l0xhjmxHGdg/fyVoWO6uR0iYrMvzNPW/xRbdFLnxu9NLlqMwip6d4zay8KadStWgd/snrFTw8UK2qVtXt@vv38dom5GkyZacRvLqRHd5Hb@on0UiTrsePLctKsdOh127Dz@mxOr9/OMKfRCKmMOGg1LhbeTDpkNtkx@x2x3vGlLtbkTF@9kci7pNvvHjxAg0v6GFvjyICNofop1FqGLkI09P6n/9k7Sp5@ayx9effGqTMNfwc4ue7V0/QfKzlPllb@@TBg2w2CbTh5mffePb1nZ2d7MNk7lktt51V0mtbf/ana2u6vqWn1uqep9WjtbOzL2Q9nZXVP/9RtPHs2dc8r5r5P775vqrhaxNe51gy@GSYBkZ8F@CnoY51xt7Cc9Zh@E/mt@2Q2UBzs/OWRd5GgMu1yJT@GpGgzNaYVt3e/C/fP3wTGUWqeuqFC99R5E0kX4hwIxjAlvFt55FqZAuD5a8i01SlUgHj5n/5txC/@lWAgz7TLXhVcz6s/DRSVSoU5V2kmgeDpuuQ7v/1zW@GmIeLiQqpcf5zn9XgkbOburxdh2eDni0JzxtT0qnUNf7TCve0e4zZo97IdPBj8Y9t4sHPShl63Ue1RCJRVxV41AZFSmmafgoCgM2xFo23EJWElbuwsFvAJ8IF/F5EiKeAqYivuFk4EKtxhxfXw71Y8JRf/GM/R1Ikv3bffFitgijMVDMb1QQ9a6elEid/im0WZMe5L7MNKLM0vR7DG@lVlVm6oMvJZPI@UlJHmiq6oF8keipHI5FXM5L6lI2wmY2FnehNBcFmYZaFY2xxuD18/uJ//Ysf/MX36e8H9PsPeDSb3bY6qQ1GNee8yh9WrcpVV748JQtkOF0qlAqpxtVpbAMkVf2IaelP30VzmegxthL0nMb9Ec5I8FSr@KJ/YSMTfa@5CZ9qYKEQsyirwyGnUbrQBIsVbErtHLCpznJ04ymy@1BKsr5ZlOtVPacfVuW0JvNy6617zBHiILINzxr80T88gXUNR5HXyG3N96FQN5@1RRhw8q5@pEitlqqbdVBkWZCN@2ultUIpX9JTjWVwEXR5YWog7861VrPZfNtqGvA0jZahjYzxfXVTLaj6ljExpsaoOW5OmqPWuKVpUuR9bY0d8VpQZwn/OU3c@jxX1YYwksHBn6I4k4gU@Ud4qhKLXMJTf79Rew9MLZKuiRqc2FLq1YTACD5q4349oVxd1dSXiXJZ/G9VA2OZHm6CjNSvFGXrJcCq3YTKgdJbbbzcArCJrdpWxdmln9pA4iv1l9Xa1nxcEf3@/QRK3/sAoLpeZ9GsE80791k8kVhXlLXa0jwA4DroLVtbULRXW1fVq9rW1dXWFvxv0ftKfMH1auvGP31mz5IwM/86VqjTWqp6mjoVDFUHu5qqoouaOgVDFb4QDhooKQIqy0SKbLCNyJBpmxkwMbOkbeiZVG7ySX4PVKVaXcG@TUWpaflcXeEy7JXKSgo/6V0r5OMqCqmG02ng5kyVvZIirz58@T/j7/TDl3@AGgBoaEUpktrAjkOR9x/g9cRmT548wd8T24Z/@D3hj40u6PDErj6xyZc7kOGJH0o4c5e5SomCg8l6IS83EtpUZ5EtOb@JouMXbjzRaPSfvNKLm1Hezcb9jK88cPyFRc8/@YVljxR5V0Rh0PIYz54UgRKJKEpVilS3BriCDUeuFewkfF75Qnm@o2Cv1hjRXESL99gqB3uVYrHKB93XnxELbTzcgLcG/3trnoe3d2Iyl/hqvsG/x2/x780I/05a@Hf0Bv/YyVv8OxrhH3vSxL9nHv6dvMG/nSb@nQzw78Eb/Hsywr/nXfyTIhVQ79e30/10K62daWdgsFjaZeleuqe1NWqP0iZLT9NTlh44WhtMJvylwWSlOyzdZWk7bUMw8AXTiKVHaOrApwt/HQDkwp@FKyTOtHSLQUJ9bKnoGihKIJ1@B7I@firVoOcqvzJBG1c1Na3mrTqen1@T63qxwFQsM7VRe3UarePBrHoxy5pTc@30FYt4oMmXI6nT0xQfk2B6toxH7V9dNRp7Tx82GimUc6dPnMPZ/@HhIGxd@T84dJ4cOgMH/g8PD58ws5q4n1Duw1OpJrbEZztSLW@flhQUCr4ciqS2tk@rGQXN@QSqIOiW@MhnBhG@1bVTKcpAQbookxpWvjgvX5TJEFjB0CgHAUQwbgDHslDfwKXs63EX8JxfkCO@0Hjx4jQwcUPqxcUpdkegnxn8g54btv5X@Lf@3/X/5DmL1eqgVsUur7Zi9MTxLx6/vLq8Eu9qPBYTltgW/KED2DHK5VUVjRToEky1WLwev7ribvCOxbc4wCqmsVWlyLOAIAIiQZqULn/F/ut@MW3xnOIR7sZsgcDp6SSdjpeb/pHRODlmvKN52niZLgBab9a0@p/9iA4G345ToFy2XNY2GLfoWb1czvq2zUK5XPAt67FY8eZTTW9redCrstl4vFwGy7YPNg3WAGwBwPqWHEA1PaNF9b4cuTw4pCOzQUzkInHMERcMsTSdrI@XtETlknzvXkxc/rq9E793Ty@m370LXIZDcNLmnBqNtuU2GuieefdObsg0YV/MgT1dePdOSxcTWjTuuLGneLsPJBVTNPaJXqVUi44LpNgEb6al9BkePcMzRiM39tYaJmVc7@XJcbp8I5123NPoT7/3rW@dRisVWZHJNashAEyF5ba28tlqNZ8Fc74AtJLXL/k9NN1EUYtfradkTg8mr0cjwksrbMa5dIyiP7SabLsKVdzD5/IqQuXOsrl4DMRrHNS4qwj@cWetWOTu2XyskCiKv8pavAr6Bf/DXnEmkd3Y3LhfZ/Q3WfigSC5fmhXtqnJplnB08arcEhcr4vZQ8969TBFoWkiXT6VG4@HOyU6jUZFlGRtFeKEjCXcJ73MautEaFXiuWK9h7uqn0WipfJ@YQyvkWCRaFuGUKLQSrFAkIkhWB/d@ex6TNDHmsCbp9MWXJEad1sAxgq3y7Pfs8c7u3klS3wJ9Sd/f2U3qx88fRDS05mZ28s6g/Whv5@Hhc4jw7PHezvHepwef7z1/Bu4eu5g9vgQW79k3bFpgv2AvpNfuW8M0DXNsmo2L8fjiDXttWQ0LCNsfW5bldF3mmQ3TNIcQzH/K8GtZnvH6teEO6WEffvidDz/8bz787vc@/O53PvzuD3765Q@@A78fw@97/Pu9f1PM4funX/7z3/vwO78Ljv8Bfn8Mv5/89Mvf@Cb/kf1P4PefQm5/In6hcPwnAaxf/umX3//RT7/8ld@E378Uv9@8@fvVnyz@/eDby38Y7/u/tzrM9/4t/H6fw/LDfu93uBt@b4T/HR7uV37zw6//O/7/Z@IPjb/74df/BF/C8s9@88/@04dv/XtdL/zZv/7w7e9/@Pa3Pnz7ux@@/U/1D7/xr7V0@PV7H37wh3/9R7//13/0P9D/j@n9@3f5//Cb/@wv/5e//N/@8o/E7yfw@3dg@slf/ntg2L/7wx/i//f/8O/@@If4/z/9q7/7w1/7u1/@H8nwW9zwf//Lf8Pff/Or//Fvf/u7f/2Tb/7tr/3kb3/rD//6f/@V//M3/uPf/Ld/8Df//bfQ8bd@8td//Mt/9a3v/NW3/8VffevLJe/vrHx/eQf3L/8RXO6O513g3CVfH@vy5c@Fzz@EGrNUgE@Au3/pw2/8IjD4rzP24Ts/xkXO8Fvy/2NdozA/5rb/Dxj0m3lGnzSY4PdrH77zPSTRfwckgv@AXt8NLHM@3PLdmQXI@tsLIv3ST7/8Fz8iW8QsVWkkGdvRgl5IbEBfY6NYFG2pGGSGKL84Dy0AIFL6LkqoOb/vomz78MNvfvjRP/3ww9/68MNfxlZMyRaTO0lFWz38BU2fkrtDOAyYv0s4DPgFpp@gkVkl8QXY2BfC84svvpAa71K4mv7@O3D9gpz4w7gXrrYXXr4fuuPye/aOhc3CmBbGdeEapExYYKoJ0gA2fPUkl2GThEBoguN@@AV3CDTZIOME3@SK3hMJX7P/mXEisQSG4Q/eP@QbySDiiSS4UcpBMonJxCcX6UuM6ygb3IXmrCjdbJFhDiaTxAQ6omCAFBLg9SDBKpVKAiNWOD5g5ahVC4xQSSQqkG@MzeMkGwUEMXlAUCBmJXHEGhuVCY@YQHhVnxwJCZ2OZE2XE4XKQ0iwMnnIEBYCJ7CvXlWqhcqkiuDec3okJokHhBMCqyQm1fdgrxDMBA5UPXwPqBQqiUS1gAliJnnxJBu8kHKUOcp7giVEGcAXh4G37zP2iawVZD5/soYE46HxnZiF3qYJvW3wP01siOzQv2@k3wYRfI2SEqkw7r9NGuI2VxoxAMBVFFVVGfxwlnCb3QfvCQeVoGThk@AQEsQRxAGBA7AhlkWCyjdBFkg/Utn46AeBYWbW19elSFXOyIc0nZSAvrp7VuL3x7zjHaISk/NFGZ1NWmbu4wLxy5T@ehRHBqOMA2afJPjv/v0N9glkk74zN4kpiYyTxTF7hLKVSMg6wK86CekldA0k4FMC9E5SJxWarkpIySRjaiWCfuzw8FAgQQ4vK1IC2FzPaGjH@YXxeByBGKqaVJNJ8VXpSw6qMKjkK77qOhKXRjKZrmfL0H0pM3Ri4e6GBv1SdHz//j2UCq31KB1Aj5GJZR96tkCe4MA3E/f7U387gp4tSry7zLR8FrrSdM8jPHEWl1iMbcQlviqYI@E/saheKEQpHFBfjW34q4DyGrEDDi1Gqoio//AeXCEX9z13D9nu4ZMne09PhvU6k0y6g9NsDF2nZXpeDP12nj7kGwP0Yj4eqdUQ9ElJRwEj7ZXSJP4OHh4dHJcYz7QoghghVqaBYZHNoiZFhsMXWxGxCkLGC18c@RjfpVneYnoxA1EjVSnSMrFHAbyE//ArS0@87gNnAh3xpCwntTz2r@I0oMqkrztjhmeR8Y3LUKdwnbi6tUUUkKqXCo1/oxFKKy9Vq2L9ENOk6vHeCUQ4OWSanlal6hdsomKCypVU7Vf6pt0d9dZxIY58mpZDeVqvpZP4p2cy8Nay@aSW26yvrfUvFUzzlIrtEldUXYH1UsFsfAUeJn1FYl8BJ3ggDVwmxcQatYPDslgohKd@xPhqIVnLQTWLS6dQ0BycNAw/5SGwN/S1Qz8psvaNb4xYtQqdXOVgX4qAuOgxf7GMYrXVnkrl3B67Jvl2GWtbn1t4lY/atrxh35hC3QFyRK6urjoA6WCf6VWdrDxGG99XLXJpgvlqYkgRu1SqvNeym1JWL5XeZ3RdAgcp8vKlYVSrtXT9MrupZ3PZnJ7J53ObOhCtmM3nCpm0ls6nc7quFbPZYqG4ecViULKGoVQrGT0j/f/PnR6aTNgaVoGcW6khGA0wZrdSBhibYMxtpZpgtMBY3EpZYBxXM1p6KzWuSkza4gdvMdzXW5FH5gTP@eNuctUz@x0VNxdUZEpAl7fEQZZVEa@KuzQco13BzZ@4uj4Wv5TalbbTokvIpLbadNpT1RtN@7gKv@@4lSioVlHfw8J7XXFLXKXG6urQGUITqOc2EzUtDYIYf1ohqSfbaqtvGu52rpQroCWYItnOpUsXlt12LtQvnjx@NBoNj0xa6L@dLZbaKp6ugfvgtwulXK5eq8lyokbJ1PFOQ17LlbU1qBmm0Vbg23HskafohTpEbltupRKNbmc0XdFKmXRBugqyLwHhME9VCWMmMC9JJN6lqEYl27GhypaSRtK6pHyXOp3O1cZlYmaRjEuF24AiV4qRbF4G1rISCldi46RizTzBxehAi3Ip5odKsp4ryOVaeWbfzMvl@pV0f2C2LQOX95@mL2/GyoNo41AjkNApk65KruOMSk2z47jmLGBGy/sBOUI3A2TlqyC50zSmeHkzuTwGAhpyygGn8mPOqrSkrQZioL4H7WCtvuUfgIYcquuKnlEymqJl8P8Wg47/dw@vw7@Ob4iV0aUT3AT8FIQyNCQ2e4xbIkcOO3EculrvgdlaEmK3Z9DavV3X8bx/QJgHhn3GvR5a/OStwOuRgXdqeANr1FsS4vlwgBsjTfcfDcLeoAkIUsWmAA/g5fYdZ1GATfb82ZJcPgnOugRi8MMuIfjRwaePTkLfk72d3UdSnj04fPrw2icnAuXY4739k8C6yX39qLkAxNf3Hj@@bhWf7OHzo87YcfEn7R8@z85egRNuB5Oy8MwHCpwJiHihldQWHDteY7lN36BJuKD4HnS97gljLj8zptH4gu91s7xggSvf1FiSTvwNcAZDAdQ0WYvvf8W@IB3hIjRFbbMoSUNmOxdsM83aTr9v4FWlnTVw7Bm4scdEdalPN@pi0heO229fWG1zTXqCe4iKGt7HiEhIjwDIYNyi8xKskYQHgrXxElGcqWj2xyYb40W9Sxzhg05odK1uDxqYC8cPIDUNg9Ealo97IL4ZfkarHUY8DXK74dO/GVyKSMbIiBTK9@5pz1yoKdV0qdQ19ybApew51BrDnSYLOVltyftMbURY16p59SGUVCab11DRAu127TR9Vso6bD3lDKuGB41RIlsD/XDUaZWhicuVgMjQl85C@6Snd9M5V5YfGdhoYOvxN7/947//0187YgUQexspeEU0WcY1zWuapJJCrRcLuUIxoxeShWIhm9PyuVxS05PQF9ksgjqa1gpavpAraslCtpgBXiyCb664KUX4grHUBoGEbwnA2i28O3CLdHK1B8o3n7Vib2NGnEWMwD5msglxZLwt3hvRpskNqwKNDtPSLLPJAKLBWiyyv7@b3t@X5Qdowdn63bQst9GSK6TTmw9k2SSf3QKqErLD4xTwCBZ5xC3p9INdWR5zAHh6qSz30LKXxwEcWbbQsruzv4/pdNCiY3wIdsZ9uKXvWzYhmI2WTIYDeBNAg2A7PJ0sIbqHFkwSffa5zy74yfKnPjroc8SDcQCP/Jzu7MjyAbfs7KDPLmU7xxH9DC079MiyCxaoFrLcBUPXhQopy00wYuWQ5RaYWlMD3PCeRjzg0h4Zsjzl5EECyfKEQhutM1lu@O6YzOcCmxxSt0QWjef6PlmK@CfLuo80BssElowsZwNLFvL26NHnRm/UNrv8mbr824KcPnqUMazJeG@/@emnzW636U539j49Qq/d3UfQ7k/HbrPbFBGbDXgciLX7SDfOBtPrD@T6oNEoGf2FXp81GlnDvubVmDZMxBBivQHMxNPFhAaNXfDafdS4byyaRCSADZQLA/g28XkwgO8Do8m9/Ie86DtpNuUysj/qyHSJM9REuk85OTBarlNG@6Syxlg0Fk1Oa/l0vUwebADacLp8Rbc3x/Bt4IBD/HJam1TS9cqksqnz9SedmHw60XOWnFwbbGvFXGnN2Nb0bGJSwg3ZTifKooq2zWLavY23LPY0vq1nsiX5dHtbkWtafVvXCqX85suNsSzHS/jezmyWIGA6Cr11fMVrm/XtzVwoyuZmwkjppc3NePkK6DGChr6JAwGNWOzCNM7icUQXu6WQBX539JTyaZU7sUlyUuF4sWm8PKloZX6mG0vfgNXGA0THrZHjcohdADfZTpfodmpZKxZkSD@VisXjIO9INMF3tnTtxddOzk5OvgBJCH140V1@xq88LQvrp492VehBCxse/KnuY1/EcdVdFFdzPvxcSt/pBESu@ghaVuiu@G64ScZ1@urepGUOsUPje/jHuaniEC715NEcnOMe9EH2RS/IK9MRFXbLZHguqtVmRqUKJqPNYoQVM@IX1KY3qtVKozLgF0xXg1ifMTo0dAbmwOO4BzufKfolbhwRHo1K@qrcrEwiE4DTqDBFezVw2q/0RKvcxuNQH1QeYORyA77Nslkx8ZptOSKXO9t2hbGx7Rkd85np4j7@g8N10DBwN0msw8z4OjulS7l3Ua2/Uqous2eYPR0PYtBlb8bnnUJWJE3sa36WL2l7E07MX5U7FRZ7GS@/Aau7zmJt9UF8O1tuxx6wRhxc0q86rzpMZ/lsme4pjCEkqEREG7rsOl6pfgZKEQd8VioBIqKMzwAmpgRgrTZ5GPGhdVVuVfosprAJixN5suVupYax3@FrS5HluqLU3tWlqqK8kKpQT8vTiFHxxk06Q5ulm5qezpcn4KZtZss9KFjj5aTsVoZj1yz3wSrGjvguLqMM5ASqAZi372IffvGb8S0lV@FuZQL1rg96SENtVCZlG0/lAZaoZCrgkahl00no7sJrMwnNvJ5PavlkJplNKpvoCm18MpcER@jygIIR68dkxuRkepJWtaRmaslY@pXVfhVPnsVAjyGSsXhy5OzhHd/gAoWEXElW@BosntA3@gxKwWHGlkJsCpKijBkDmvfY0Er2ENSRafQpRjyusMxGrL8ewzDrJ@PhXq1eKu1Nhl8Dr5jyZjuf2Ewn3sbj5dhavALKkFQtS1WUKpTr4RrwrBhWY954UIMyHq1rm3qpVmtiDjfTyUw6A5mzGu@6W3JVrifTa3kNSuiKkXbEuMDgGtJMx5m5NVAR75tQcFpRL0sqreCgFLWYXtTjEi4SFDGloZBqSEgWO5X9DYuxaHRTj0bj0TKOea/JYpATRBmJsSjI1Og9bVsG9UsuyUUdA8wkIu1JS4c1sCsJFT6WLUqRS@nq8moLurkpWrOHWuUamRS1el@KlBgDNfBUnHqSWmPsY5cCJraqL/n3FFciA1yJjs8DXZTW55gW9s3Y57j/dptFATHDHdR0PVOv6ZvQkIFw9IPqulbGcf4ILnlWq0Bi7xLw20pUcevKZ2w6NRKKP/B8j7FuYl2iTEeuz@XtVHa6Rztl37aLQ5mnkizL5agcuYxGolfwJ0Xu034Zne@XYZHQjhkcy8axYqDP@wiJBrZ76Q9BlfASl5hR4oKgVo@/f2r1LwsZhY8zgGS6uoqsp6hExLaD8mev9ByUke34@xCgb4QaObRRuRyOw0ZSr4beN/RC5snBof3Q3TfFLoRCtiFXIyytKbiqv1wSrjm@wlguFnRZP0tG2P1IOcLOlKhWop0Kw@Piy82XhZdPnh8@P9yXIqdr79YcHGFnPlXYe/urX4NORTSTjTJ2WolMKtmyWJBVrSralo7HCW2yEgj1jpZX0u@qnHur5JHXwefDL/5mdrJVALue1sCu67mEXq1qGzqLR4YfvvwDPEficu/znccs6hlT9vd/@iN98@//9F/RQqfoVdmj8eDNCIREo5bfjFxeDi8vr@DhfrlIPcKRym7GwcznDbRINaXpGdu2y6yUMoyNzURWv2@XUyKstqnFI54SETMgm7mI90546ekCePlTFOQk57EEIntHVk7X7m8hT2jBHioW/G2ZXhGYovDk1TvGwNKqtrtdSydTKsVK7xW29V7ZYu9xVuC9ssZeVao4q6zhzit/0HwDN5jgzFG0mkhtRBn0cVi1dlWuJxgNu0M/8aVpbtin1zj6dA3Xr887bdjwZ2549IeRfAcPrL7N3HjtybGNeCrVbotTh7ZMlqsCK2ykALPT@Idf/A1dz//9n/7qu8a7xhc6dAGLxbymR36m/exnEGDF7n@//0azC7hNHw1Bv48tud8burdSBC997zAe3u8FYr8P1QSra0OvHm3SOao2VEoNfqRUO0bBNnBzcJIUZTrwJV6WpEChJEXY7baSBINt4N0LUEulS@kr6AXtJ6uA4JS@MgMFDgNoMZ1Ww@uP3SFtKYhRPK2eZPcgCqTwFTyta402NQvpq4DASm3cjMpR9ohqpAaxgel5ePYXNBzSVyCKOCcPr5Q2cP89hrRsEPcqBiE8yaNdg7TrkHafR2iQa4xyzwMkGceOR7JBWZa@Au0/UcECtYBZWxCgDCLmK0AAyENMALbqbItl4uzSSiTKs4PFrnAFNR6CZvh7fyWMhtDauNfcj1zGcOAESjrezIR8IUoYNLKQow@Ew@BzvRVQ8zE62VDPos35dwYFsOggnBhljd27N8OqUrHacUY5Qvhn1hDHrqgc7MW4AjC/i/RJuyQnGR7ZVvZdA7YDiicIXeA6hZ/VVg5FZTJaryQJ/u/MtMiR14qKPMqYAVFevFa0gGQQGcnOy7DFtipM0zfjLEC@Bbi3CCk6Jizo951OPlH1L3zPK8DwZxH/3HMQRCfh8UDBt9c3fzNoAMd46DQeAcSFgdi0zQ/5QYF2MPJjB7EgK1afQncsF/okNAntnxgWy2hxjDY7YY3woDXRepbh0uRcHD8UC0Mz@Bp4NpZIZ43O92g5UKDe0LHpMC06@APXfQNHgIwSZxJxtMf2BV5SIMqGIocx8ug8IuR8xJgOB6PbHSkuzgI3Xei4@rRJMrOrstagzfQiixGj0dlJdgAuTpEI4SYouEjjZt8cAErHpkm7crxSKtUF/WjcpAOknljAV719C1oV20uJizRTF9aZlTrBQ5YVp4Obd/h2/AiqVFj9@ISzOKyp7zhnrG@dmXyYNzZ3mIHHQMUHPTUJlJ39gLAlXMmgZ5IsDd5JHgp@m/DZ5MZCMhR3LTaN3/xmtLVYA0v0HTUylouXZJ4bdoi@9LyTRK/Wm3r@cSh0qAfY1UDkmuIghEoUtzgHJ3xI4mCXCp0pouL0wTAGfUz/QBQ0gvptnjPsn0rYxoDQbPlHC2Athtx@hRoAqntQs/BstJFbwgMxABO3HWtB1RMC3mafsIwuYUB@Wo04WQZgYNFX5qGDH0TFfHijNhSMyjergVyB2jlogx9uxRbsh/F97kYznVs3Y2@2JsBho0NpVRivFr4lF7Jg7UB@pqyvgWceMFyAyVpMTgDYhByXOegg/vXonNslkiUldhNSkiEEQWqAQqqCf4suC90mIIHHA8PjZ2mKU9QuLi5UOs5v7Fqq6eEJ@x5eDZwadi3Qjp3UyBwMxV1mFt5hKeDOTAq/WAMvjN6e0FXNxXtT/pWkjlcR60Fi0Y4XxcbxHA@Q7w7oGCA8f8cjhtq36PKJVkwsT@H8p9eTlz7/lZD/lEL0CoEwhmAmyWmylQRgyWbrLNm5aJeFxzlVSAAOpWj6jniEputbBp5vsoadIIQzoj0Wvr3ZP6OpUIAk81HYWdI8h37IqW8V9qE1gUi2ecF2XNeYxsg/jqGRgWNTUnvYFJp98gEjNDPskp/naE1q0/pc9EkQHRo1v/PDXDzjR7pcDZQf7on@E@4/Af8J95/MEvWTrU3qXCVDpyvMDnI9Hg3nh0QwUz/MFT8Ic@ZDkEHHZhoHgSGnc25X8GtVKLZPb26Dcqz4jAE8MQSCm7FU7eVp7bRue@bFRj2R6gKzy0QIKHEAXasTTS/agRmp3z/vDx1vzsnGEwGhVRJ4o1OrJ7iB8wrmMSggYgxOLwsPcesOxBICrhCIDAME1MPAE1WDnVHMipeDw2TJExinJs9ozBGrCWTqpH0JL@EG6hInPSdsGFA9BAjdgywBmuDD/JrD71PxpcMLF6@N98MqdAXEAA8TitajQMlrVYXLmjIVUggrRfHRBLKjulq5nhXfH4qids0rlM0rUf5h9Nc@Gv0O1IvF2BPD8gajLIWrCi5@AxVCVBeiKqtWQuUKGKQ2jL7pQsu1x/VT0VpDMhspv5vB08EseBd4SWwsVPitOC8f2vcm23IpYIVppQJZnFZ4teT1wicpJ3gQzRPRpj4jiPhcgACM9MJopog2CUebVCpccLDJkmgXISQnhOSER@GhJ0uQrIto0HsKbhfH4qmDdoqr82SAp/FmFNSgoczwplic0X6NB53hdKdIcyZziAsED6GKjXzWqi9MvRZCOiS0rgFARrwBoM2vZitJ1wWepgS2QEZxUvoyitsEG3BZAQxGIrjMDwONBUxGfWBQ@OUEtQNQd@VETZI1GsrFvzT/yUnf0f9pNx3T8yG1ecd08trfP4pjHSkbqqAh7UNLZ1EgY0/muS1O0QvrHBG8xbTngFbXvHBYbIGyDe6psYiaavadZmpg4MoUvLBJXGI8nMb9/gNOg7D7Q2dkjJxstsQ7TRax3aL0eZ/B6toOnvMeOgQYdL22Y3p2dASF2nK6tuWZSYZntZ2ZotthijPHpbCeLIyOJ0liNJJ3YxE05ytUdRsNvEKy0Yjhurp4KVilS8vskD2jUQn7v2AKxQfxJIAeDmNO87XZGsVvh4nnVYtoJ1brLHY4FJ5RSGSHgQxrgf4Pvj3QYJjnzHqOdHIuqtLNUYwugOg5A6cLWt/YUyWMfQ38wQw2ImQMh4RLkhnYpS2FTi2nWhJrJY24iPrZR0dln@kxIx7E1@cBzBEjydzrNEbKuguSayxNjkfz0zv@eHyPw/ger8aXeuHXceZd8wr3/LikM7EZBAg4QyNzOxqYdZBb7RvozKESOKNexSPcGcU2rfxqI6Y7EHRHBFc7wB/JwOaBLUD882X0X12AfvS9uxafgffqHk9B3gxwQWKM7hzw/PnMGAQ/iMelyILkAtZ@eMe0ICzeirSPKgSosSS4bDz0EyrmELrdXnAUvQ/4Fp7HxVY3@J5WYFW45wKc3PMkO9OXF9HDRtvsG1OzHRMhkyG4fo6PoMNG8upuGUdBR0LP4X29GLRd8cAXmnEkOg9UWsIyRvI8Hl/OVjyIFXAPjZQThgfL6Yf@N0QzDvFV@Gg19AOi0QgOx55bOPw5nA6n/FzpPr9RRchR3v7wksS9/bcTBOggDs9JzpKNrxKfR7EgS3doEYKw6nyW8dhXHyKePXOzDD@ORLfnFAo3FKnil7I0f0fC4hK3VpV4iCt8nuRTSHdjyduY7s48F2I1DmwmwnY/rgm5ARmXYLRasTBE7rKyxBz7hkxANxqns5e0Ko0FAjWISZJuZFF3m/SLuIQ94wP44oDT5/BFgF1z1OAM5ecNx7TEHS6MfAbGMKS1CBdQ0gFKiIqc5AKNUCjJN0Pwy6sgzdbSNFs30mzNpRnUgPkkQ4Gk1lySohSweFYVQd/sjJZIZ/TCvjN8VolteGzHcHG04jJqRUtWkkXPoyUQyFEzWtqLgVCOtqOlh2TwoqVjMpxFS5@BYVa3ou@iJb9aYAAXrGS4j@5ChKO9FS3txuJX0sg4Mz0/XTVaCsoUwmxzK1EESIH5Bq0Rp9hsR2Rz5JrQsJFSmWTIMV4Su080DpOkXxr@@a0ndHsCeuIY5wYFZgmmzTUaoRaDpwPNhn8694KaXBKt@d7hPi1hCoJgMgno44XjEHhQwyPReWHEEUNfmtGALyCIcrO0GCMWasnuiI5IHTiUCnk@faKeSvpAO0b@NQhcnyVCV92I@H55zYPgBXg3PDHyMjxvoOMnRxjhnGx8AVpI1FfRFZnCsp7HRZR@uIRorHs@EF5M7QfhpURgQzIddDianMPEhs5wnknIF9fPW@E4NCjHKyVy77VoJBVEzVziTc4iZygYwpU/vio7oXiI2pwIQs9aus5rWdAukCxGr5msC2mqvPIBCiGZAzXcbJ3RNUIPhZHCcXGTpLZiWTPkx@VJkuSaF5MQWcVDisbGiKcedF738Oiij@u@@jEnONYSQwChmEEqXL46H6G/O1x/9xVqnwjXElikWC9uSm@q1ytb2WuY92fJ3ixA9Eyyh/GFylGQwozk0DsIaeareO2Gio9LPriSzxMNoF/T9n2yBX2CW@h2vW/BYaGW4J7PO57p4HimLyfUTY2kf676SouKKQk4POMBprOsrcaVZ3xREaMPjW8b/Y8uYHe@gMOFh/AoA@41kvNa7o5tWuUyq9sgtrkLilStxLggp@nSoJhnjiDuaeo2mLYFh8PG0cPDp4@/Do3u5uZmXLTR0xl@WGtxrDVoxzlkWg8dtAcLui16Em8GwcluHI6nS@DXTm35hizhwhqUAQNS8dlP1PG4kGUheX6t7kI8HjZEUQHrbFYNjDmphKqOgU22Jeg6AoKYo9iGIYD46i3QO0m9tTjdgdFo4MXfjQY1X40GLl5qNEQrhkXjz4jHfxZZS409ly5D5Be4XEgSnT/AHh6yF492TtjJoz22/3z3M/b1w@fsxc7TE9x6/uz5g8cHuwx@e0@P95g0t1ASL7vCDiXQ9aHZMvFOQjzhLcsI8q4znHK5E9uNc/djY8AeOS0Tp6m2PGNwv8ctqm2OqjzWHnRHpziGadGFZgNrhOst6DYu6MaictOmPX@4fJ9B2Cb0aQfY5x04batjQVgJ@75Dy/T8bWKsb0EJgrz19/wmuZKEF2/R0iG6Ig9XYF1AdAPC49wNgDH4@iu6W93yeASzrTJBuOD5aAqe7B09OWZ4isHu4dOHBycHh0@P2f7hEVifff3g6adAz4Pjk6ODB8/RiwI@OXx4sH@wu0MOHIG0yvB4gddjb7QSBRWDE1VaZzjzrQ6h@APb/Kg3avDswqDdjx6Ljm2UPpbRt96a7WhZGnuovuCOS5oqYLH1naNPP4c2n5lvcIbTnwqm9Qfyc48ugFtPsy1KDSpLFepbWVRXaPYULU7zEYMpw/sgzDIdOxAjc5L5wGkRT9symbyLa1Rw7JufTkB12QcNCa0BbATlL1ipMLrHJRpNbhHIKqTW6jt4viNPjS8iFBaMet9falKWiGJirQwCxS0KBzaOB2nlwAH4Hhx0kezI5QFYJnDgAViWO6AqeoBrR1hOhBiPDsconlmeO7weDPdpWphtBg4PDOrFFgROvNyoSA0W3IOFZzX06bYePspDtwgaXsuyKIpH4fEmm36fVwyT36EGMpFPJdLaNggpg7Dp4FSDWPbGLxtFX@AGXCdkdEYei1XiKjvBxUGmbfF7krp9w@ZLoGZLd4j3WAGPxamIE8mt4H4h2vQxdIgB8W6zeTyCeA@FVmjeNR7EfHAjRUOskaQ7/vwlaLch8OAGAj8PGACkzPV0WtRS0YZUBON0BCvHPAc4Esdt34fDAzu3xy1zLoJYtRV7bb19GxdETs71k/x1ioQdFNFb0wW1kqYyO44LdZzEKt3IglKw1XOGI4uXYWw@BzTjRM0chMaGDVJ7VanOpYZ0uJ6i7dihRJvAxUtSbQJT3iVV4ng@dx6Ir9n1nMD50AjzdXeIjvH/FPe0W23kSv6mn0K0SeiGdtsmgRCMSQyYxLN85GJIJscQj7HbxneM7XEbsCcw5@7@2BfY/b@PsK9y3@H@2qe4Wx@SWt02hGz2nMk5wd0tqVQqlUpSqap0gVfIR2dnHh4i3QaofoGFMJ2Vo/JzMiJMeP1pRbLjD4E3/K0Xtna3z9J//OLhNX8sFvhmTWV0iP@BMbEuGB50zkcGi0Ncd8mRpq5nCq8vsLS0wZPSEke5Agb7wMsO7Ove1vI6jc2Np7@jW0zyO328uytwqTRKJnnZanjpRNLNE1VVpUdlzoU0ATFkJyALst5RXzyCqeX1W3SFwV7IA0V6KEdw3564/EiKENW6i@sWSBZ5B6Xsbg3fFVtkURFdyYs@LmZ/ZL4424XlLTcTGZQIg5yOEtGegpxzXcMshearKXC7j4MD@f10cOuPYsfTw3dB230U2nfhll5@GBZPSwasp4P94xGwPLn9n8BC272HAfMkOQ1Nc7pmTm8hpa1pH6/xl6m@o7EHYHDuRQ2KBmrUdt2jI2oVTdnhAq4JJloQVU52S8fHwub9CZQFuYdbhqYUgwh7XnyIrG07PRJ2vl406c2yXjypLzGLNvXvscE8k3gPiAq5BvEkPbSwiC6fbnXGLPXkzEJLCLK@J4GoKBfH7quSQWFVAr6HPSAgG3Wa0UBrZjNTPPl0QtMIXNLN47WxacNPFtY8d@PNjsOJCci0Caq30bNkdv994vXxhqqHF1gY1Qcb3ISVNMw3sE@oQMUDyOj78R58pFtUl6KRPS@wU4p2aPiVja@wf5yhiJF4Ec5rYUOsy8WxRI3XxwtqmUMGiTgN1NHSUyayRTMkKBFPXzbNDnWjSc@JT0GwyMS7/t6aXAHFz@/z@vZ5J5onC3pBbo61BcKmqrA8R@2shJ1/ONMztIVeS4qHZFUgbR@tKv3/UxXPErGaFM1nNkYlAuS11dUX34KdbIUqnv5R2DyHJOXn6GoA@/sIZDgJSb0PnFs@9FR6xACPkI5N69WASRSEpc6MOSXWdpqMTPwAF9YLATIYxRyvT0zW6opxArfZ0HlGMqFTlqk2GENYN5RHzRT17x@vDgXyN@ub//76eLBhJjQdvEer/IP@MAwirzwjHIvxCT1Z49@C4bBH2dif6QqhOOTG9KizHXnbscErtwoT6bzNbElLeiex2a2ndA1UCakXfbwxFbV7@aR6L53Lm03dK@@XxBJFN2zFdJH20HYN2TPf6T2GAMlg0kvg9EE@fM/CDfgPOHgKJJCJvPkcoo37TdyIIrBqrtLdMtIsVMrWXLL3W2Gj3sMoHp79LBS29xwKkha2dLTnztKsZ/Ox8oBcOOg5UMqz075NReEbKnQRUhwE9yZ@NyYs9NRQlpKP3HNfz@TWs2uvLWpdzxt5V9XX595So2ALmHzrvavwenjb/LXdv7xpia4Y/PVi3Jj8/psQqy/FC7z67jmHmM2tFTIU1fMV/F0Xr7PEuRLBNxQu98wWwue79YRYFNE@PD8v@F452jRvoIdEgkvF0pXiQnSxGxWuqmvnhV4hm7@q9s7z6OQ3Wi6MlnPLDn54DrMoyBg@ma@OznFONbWuQe9G4JWrdDWedA0R5BoCXw7qw05/v3j4LqaNwwUAqsCkrTcp1Pm21Dm0ZkPfE78X3DpSTeYJ5FgLF0jWHHkF5dC7nfTJqI5pdgAz6BUPVrPhmP5OXGsu618PRn1KUfEGkbXEXefOmlNuTFnSKECWakdFJaRL4sNxlMfBgyH@OmEr6nSOl2s59J10DRBVLEni0D6zbfQpRESlL1f13Ar9oN64RCTweuA7KiY2N@myYGC10CctHppy1IfkMJE9x0c8AIGfAZ02YBW0cg/J7cOC5uN7Dh/4C@moRuQnQwbyFq0UMQXNv8VX8m@i8ptAACb8HK@5fKnilCsvWEiy7yApFzBqWXzjj8cM6FbJnTKHjUXYXF8hAk6W4kQjrFaSCb7P3SI5mVbwT7YgnaO3qWbo/C5nJ5LQObV8C5GW1KWUtIU/3aiYYxRLq2Iqs0GKuW9SAzVdsD06CGBYTcRO0O0C0kyLuYgc@Ej@vbL@ZV1/WMU6zzXynJ6eSk/H0n1OZ6SiXD5M8FGmDTOTnfoa5bsXdpTNm6qrIGjx4kNPN3xYkkR584/lDf1Rv9aJMm/prmSu1AmbsYS0kfJlRu9zynysjGZwnV7ldMnfK7LnNZaxvG/j9eOvJTsoIONZaWuS4FK/1@m@seTNsjIF2cwGagrBxbG/ie14UEofTClOYAWHen4atluFCMpyTkkcGjP21uZb25eLjDdOEg32YpwaWDPGiEElqnOZCDcmh0Woh5LnDRAEExlNqJG7pQpPZOGJARZzzatq2QtyaoBD05JDvIB@kXf4Rw32OHIqX2p24hxjPubGs3dznEAkdOft2WSKSxN0F@GPslGPzCJR3ZMkxNlC4tDQAus6A/bBbqEafF7LCVNQKEkxRXedIikdZcgp9n2oCzHx3vpnZsl6V4c19qAbjEURtxl18sKyYg7uoyAchRjOiaLShNeDQRdPHWnBd0su1DJmyMoqHrdEEI2Z3bfKaNnD@T18kg7pUMgXRwj5Fg1EooTwut1GZzL0gO3fomhFjUtn5FvF3oQVGjBmXqywm3kgrkM@NYXdfttEgnuORw9SOhzUG4FvwRothNWPxU1tdeTNjqRPR78RDBgGU9qGZf3lutP4decdnue@ymVf5AyS3cjj4Kz/4mXkYAVEUgkrGOxvNffSsoyz4QafDacRoCf2caL/CLwZ3AS9XmAVYcagjCEsWsNgeBM0fcs6DvQhMMJFVsaTSfTD7l8PG6zcgUVXHZgRvYRDj4/DgMPwF@dnPi5u0FmZZ@GhVXTaDF1902kiAZXHSauPp8N0YIFhApgeWOgqGAFRllwRR4nOniUutHa5QkUUUAPjnBhnE5oMvf6o04CeIU2W1QVQfAwSVdZrJjCB@hrdOjoH@7MQQPeYiAIKAXWU9BgOljw0/y4chGyYOmOvq57JgPTr01iB4R4MOyB9IwJTr1AxA3fo4JP35YqoHO2dfCoelwQ8fzg@@ljeLe2K7c90xo0H5RRSV7w/2gfpok/T@dT8CD7YxQqUtCnBKh5@FqWfPxyXKhVxdCzKBx/2ywANwB8XD0/KpYonyoc7@6e7dPoOEMTh0YnYLx@UTyDbyZFHtapiVlROHO2Jg9Lxznt4LW6X98snn6nGvfLJIVaGp/pF8aF4fFLeOd0vHosPp8cfjiolgQ2zdsuVnf1i@aC060P9UKcofSwdnojK@@L@fqKhR58OS8eCjASMVm6XAMviNmxhsSZq5275uLRzgg2KnnaAeIDgvicqH0o7ZXwo/VyC5hSPP3sSaKX0l1PIBIlit3hQfAeNs5xvUAX6Zef0uIShkJASldPtykn55PSkJN4dHe0SrSul44/lnVIlL6z9owoR7LRS8gTefkdVAwygFqTD8/ZppUx0Kx@ewJxx@gHtHVzo5E9AGMCyCEV3icBoBoGtBSIdHX9GqEgH6gBPfHpfgu/HSFOiVhGpgBYVOydmNqgQiHhiNlMclt7tl9@VDndKmHyEYD6VKyUXOqxcwQxlNMj4DKwDlZ5Sq7GfAC9@BGa1FOd61J2ivCeKux/LiLnMDRxQKUtuIbLtvJc09zGsrqFE6fRRZ1C/MhUrrelPNwHGk5zWyMzW0eiISTtHuyWYkWXcKjtKOIVZZz0RSslMg5lGJ8JrLGRNM7i4btc6vVYffUx1MVZ8XIVtD@@TcfEyjjPrkeuUpH6FCqRStdrHYg02upVazfWeUjKGxrdKSDX4Y7lc2Ua8SwB33qj42dhgum/GCLX1XB50kqEeHkBgTqb@czZ9q18FrshkmoEshs77CFipjkI@NrnEoxQQjeTsiLeIRFWSZoLeO5IdqKCjwPuNGupJ0TKSMvVD@NO7i154cjA@gHRmdVcmg5tYQqPze6Cq4UooJAL9kREJOi2q0g@D4Ne2kzWrwz2/3@73m47rqjKUdwT7wLbjfqP4RdBOFE8nyxOydOwsQ/iHat9NSxh9/ixJJmS/@ENqmYN/aiP6cRU2HPMBtaZUFSmrpdLSec7F0SLJEzK0BbpXUCfjmu@g@HP5E@7msisv84nv7/V3HltoL4hxZ2HCq1K5c/p5f84ZYIBRLA4gSUdGyMhkjDLK3kRnvoWMl5jpttNEyx@Yqy8DmteBJLCQva53zTpxNh52xib2IIffHRcPtk/39kB0IrYv11dfreUtHXbrZ49/P2M9FByWoo4NYB6HdRolGaNkBxY@NFKMoNwR@xMDZzKYEUOxq06jjxjnQdttxC2ZUJBhc0O8UqeHJnp2gHSwBQXgmLcUv84cmZIBnFhTXWzNVX1MS/w6rJWIB6QxS3dCvTbGPwhbD381xHWDJANJFqNwucC5sLsguWfvKVNR2txQ4B7M4tuKjzmMm6YBqbrIfha9a@lN8rbRiyGbMuJ4pW6nkoDEfBILoewqejyyP1CcEakApuhh8OVnyW/w@FkGuKNwd/VwVBxVgIx7uiTqqSNltGx0VUI@x9txMKiaqmlToJbflUjR2JPqZB0YxBgNhApef4I2vnHAeR1HJFklWcC@XXTFV@ZUDN6BcPKSY@U7cO6s5kgoeRU/RL6rqBSCYekgJ0y1W12HpbJ81nEsFDljZPohehD8P5EmM@Bvwo4ToEfUMoIAPomSBJVpBdtXIkrnVh00GKcbETXNT58jMPdmx1zqhsnTmzH71wAJZO9M1IfPFPaw5cwgADI5KjbM8atN0i7rsHV6a7uyOJ6T9BpXA0fIuUJNFVNw02vnHi27PHW2gi@ucFnXZFS4D0XFW964XdCohy1TYisvnoU2g3NV/I/MEilA9IAnLr1kq9UkZ2XlKFNyQIZaMiacpo6YBMvS@wdP7ZaEESIzJvvlyZciFIDeQnym20l3hPQFm@fGIy7STCxOKAoehgDHbTJOPjJk3QUZYnYDhPOsScoQvEZkdIsTRJehU6i@CJpwnpGhCFYSWR1GcQZR3Lo@kJam1VuNPWkmkUM19qc9jj0fsFZL5fA5wIfE0HSX98VBfQIod5/WbGaxzFKl76HtIlbGaglZHq9MafT7Q1g61rHdgKPXmbi@@CSVDkEvvB7K@IUwn3WGUiOhFv1QDS6bePdO0wyHfSfUws4IvRWaPvEHNekqQAtRDk8yTq8JB5hX8eiWUjp2xss54WxGKZtAEwpLSkTcFGvi7o5zMUFlyNCAKNgJ9eaCbDapHjx30MPvtj/8Fed@XAL1mkFTRyY1QJIukDup3KMYj40RN33QD0mjAV2BGhBNiRwr0rShKszRryQ7SbsmO4qOibFLqSXfX49mUmUtBRVFjCtrB@ZbS0NnIpVWZGhQHSw0t7JKqMzacN0/uBmjaKHxY2thn/W0SNngRUThmVo64hPLTf30GZ@kkr/wLMTRA1/wjFsuQRFhXLPiueq0nCP80KbgUycYNk2dKKxkmvUBqt9o69PvES8q1aEM@9eoj8JgAjuARqYzzhCMmvNT/7JX2@l36@1Ov1OHfRpGbh@zxMPHCT1ih7WH/duQbgOihKaRqTmJnjm@DIdhw3d9Lpk3QnOFo2DgmGYKo@GkeMlhIkhzjkaA0T2XxN@DZIw0XeblalTIivufkj1ezs0/WPZFblZhPtFHAFLAbSUsKNiHdESOSYbzaX4qw8VjGQwcL0Ra1N0HLPZiGL8GEtExTAxjhcyUWYLZCNyZPYhxtTn2mhSDcIiBloLdAG@vCR367NXx6mCQIm/QUmBD5NazRlE@RRljHEJ8mDxM7pVXfzL2gMAPoJ97MYtbZjECibiWirYU8n5FRhkFXMg8sEMymiQxSLFOG2ahbgxobZyEGk@ePEQNsvyBRZEMszfFlTgiHdj44KV1Tg1ETm3i4qSyKBZdituBS5DiyMk@zLDBt@xnafDjIS5rzlAw7UjIjoH0Q6RqAJXwctaEea2JMsdU/vaIWVl5aq8lCFiYZXJmXBLs2GrlQh4oHZ5f8VirPwRhbCeoJ009FsNRf7D4ROo9KDtmRmabReuG637TEJiZrQCT5VKTSFuY4OMkbyXxSTBNnGJkaQY8hNtXetZsniTiuFDD8VaoTb5Bh4doFtlN6UlF93eTxz5Oijdo0asmGj2kCHcMUprX36s1aHjtYQkiYfL2qkYSo4YiozbhRwNUgkyaSk@nEHGfxD1BjyZQDuttAu3M/nmQqEkjORXyVCXFglwiPTFwOzptglwatND4AsPE8QpXCym94Bx7EzrKy6UvMMgwJjBAXBUH6UgPxRrcqLMSfES3A7ScGloL5VASwdOWaeGgg/5rglFUfqnckRYPtUk6d55nSGMNCXYVlOsxSMrfHF6rtTFBmSIFDPEZpNAtmpJNl09v1Y@2BfIBBC5NydLSN@thY1yxDNjAHzOpNsY1cFSVLBkbUfGBUCPRAGMBdintbsDbVVz9dYbM8WjdIIcRbCD4s4M/y7IEhvNey2pqY5Fxc4JZXEluHm2uSG9xkYih@B3JL4ciL3Vp4woAAsYYyhdyAAHDmhL2eChAoXdMzoshKvsIChZyOCzhI0VFjew8Z6QjUWWGl6tGjuysHK9NGOmZQGBhMTtPhAisWWZniaDARDcTFyPHq9ntiXLAgljxPlMcukL2SpyGuueYgHSdctaNJEo1J7ys5GBKfLnqxhI1f1Pq66yRmk2mAn00htV0Lpm6no2lxqpdWYkXjZUEerhmrbFEIIVrIqylwo/9I9cUM@S5tgk1NhmxVYa0z8brrmGXCfs2/6@h2CSnbLXGUPBMz3C1/arxFSuxoOyPB2AXi3RkgLHbf7i1yjJVYSLvCqC4dMrZxeENIa1YbZzqsVm401WR9nSAArWn7bfEx5O9vVjY14uJMjS6Coar2WwWmfjCDH6vbKtRldTpZ@K5M63rbjczuP1p@PEiQ7I/COhKgA21gw6gS2BQhH5/2OabIRAHyIq509KRFff6162WeQUDnlBi50G3cU4ZDUHQBNTRRi8fT0gBRCDlBPsLNhDb94vQo@@2zgtNCUUdQ0FpNAm@sdXpGZAHP7TQPlufVBEwFMzKmgnmLbew9RVnELzZhDqLwhe7XyPzZPt90O32PfEJ7xPGSAFz98kCe3tmgSxnwRNG8u69DikerSeCm07X8CvGLCavIzg1Mal7JlRceIyNfxy0S@OBY1e/2DCtQJOXsZnLGJ/aE3bbdmWw@CeAZT4EtJ@U@6o@cBpEp2RmmOrlCI6eAKMXOW/m3ieWxSWdmKTZt3MjUWej61OwBmi6S2sBFcueupda8kB2TVz7bJxrIQ2zDEPihDFXnlYCXc3@PLF4M2q1niYV6RoA7tjvkoh8E8qPCUQ6A6ARKIcf0BOjaP9LGob1XiKgCC9w8LKOabmDBWpYwLKeNQq/3TrFYlEsDJaXRbG4DQ/ptChuF8UuftjeFrvwvo3vzwsrq6t5lrm77lf4uK0@3ottgEEazuXG5XAXXiGtgH5jaK2NXbyQKSx4@YVaYXMrH2aqxW1064enf/zrv//j3/4jU5Qv/4Uv2/RS/aIz@b6fWWh8XXh@n8f36u754sJFdWFwvtjOI5f9k6KG98ujdD0yH/WHF1aKZwHjK9mRqn02RZ@RRYW63@@qPvwVpMuGSDXCTEp@DfnmKJKxqUZgfA/Qj/ICtvDq0oHkVh6QSAHQCarjoXcaARrgwXwDlARc0A6Uy/PZilLcYzgYnUGfqqRkJB5as94E6NMSRVJAX1yYsdKdXhj0UAN@Q2tebp5l1eG3M6pJ/s18OQjb2/2xWDpzxFJWLHliybbpJ7f2Gr66C5kOeudyNtgO2LYHKdHRApoZirBDCz3aP9BdOwlyW9YCXdmDkFSYCsrMXnCe3v2RswxfuBa2rTm8PlOwioQOmbBI6utC7x665SvkuLdjrja0UKjJXQxVZpyo6P7FJVA9ZEOAqOYrJshGH6rEkz7ySManjPoi@9qi24QIMJL1@N0ejXv8AHPRQk/aPMf2UnjNEZnP81ecG/PsDE1oYwrXHyFAByq8ncySJ@FiatFiK2@jldRM9sI22yeZj20dJsFI2aZzoT@EwQRszW0SbqEn/VqkITcfrwi7o49XjKrspO23sIwiV9fdUWcg3RWodhxQX3Vt9zySsEcJEMPhmP0b0yOMFAUqUlSiW/iyrIlo9rHpPBJ60jUdOtj1@eTIIELmiwNj@y4xtt0MeYkodmAeIKS0KV@r3umGMurKkIjdrg8v8HbAeosuVBvxuRnp8/DC1ATG/ZZG2ifIZHIejWdoSmowrLev6p5IHfZPhvVJGaYtWPmMGr4LLcQQTIgEDj5Z9azmKYS5RbJLiCK6KWQ5hJcXdCfyejTuW1v7nGCXqqEgw67gIIixE1EyuIv1VYKOEVd/RyeYKE8Jb30aKUUsSV60NJKQbNNthobZ1NCxVA3m2NEDx7YYVT0yFS/IQtc40V7RwS9I8i7GCJB129ILULoirL3G@nF2age9emxyGnQt5eifyQueF3E801WUbI1kqUtQc9GNd4gVrCO/xKNA8NykwhlZc44zdxbK69xS5jxCQb61LX6mLjr6Ajq6wIw8Q8Rpr8PCMjFDRXdg@KJMlv8AodWttwG/yW19gqx4lnLezGfc6pez3vmSc9a7O/vdJUykSFazbFqk5GG2klhyrMDMmPFir8oqLVShBs968QxnPcE@LAYJAJGMU/2SOb/LAEJnKbxG/izFBIl1GWKSeby@DILPTKGZimORSVlz7pKrOt95k3MFzK30i33IH1z@BSzUppLU9LDPGbYAFPnp/nbNLidhZn0l@3Il9xJ2Qu1gnB4G1zjfpsPri2AMS4kQt7Mw9Zz9HuOGGCHux2E9Dx/H0E6@1oR9T0LppCRFqBzmVI@l2QrK@MwTkB@oTOFS0cXF1XnqePiIG35PAMupvBQLik0HDe5zcP4M@1dYTz1EuZb0DmGORCsDthEhFWoaIavLVx7iUFcNl0Xyc/LFDsZuJSDQvZmUMVv0@r20XKy5/mIeF9HoNdNdz65nk2N0aojGRuiCXEwtzovc1ptXf//Po99So9TWSubTEH5Hqd9Sa@spfoQHeHuh3m5SW6lNzLZ2n5pkYA8Mj6/@/t9QfusngIMpk034s7WqYK1NUlvpAhW5S22twUNuZQXq/Z@//Q3asMA7NryLdaHmCUIsryiyU@8R70K6KGMreVu6GIkVcsxCGGxhCHtzeEHDqPHKepbUdClpVXETyMhXyh5FTvFkmDUiUyHWZCh7ClgZcYECVpBmkMqEoiUM2w1ltoHMG6Epfnnmr4WwA/hFmnPoKrXpxrMQTYYWeFsEHehwjbCf54et7Btbm3ds2MqmJK@WkLi1k7J2/UX@fwE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/vhqb6)

Befunk interpreter uses PIL, which is not available in latest Python. Pillow can be used instead: `pip install Pillow`.

Polyglot has to be converted to PPM format with ImageMagick before feeding it to the interpreter: `convert polyglot.xpm polyglot.ppm`.
PIL/Pillow don't like PNG created by ImageMagick, so using PPM instead (as with ImageFuck).

Code of image-based langs is on line 568.

Befunk code is between Floater and Piet, it is equivalent to Befunge `3.2.4.@` except Befunk doesn't print space after a number.
Befunk execution path:

```
(x,y)   Color     Funk val   Funge cmd   Comment
(0,0)   #0000AA   000        0           Floater code
(1,0)   #0000AA   000        0           Floater code
(2,0)   #0000AA   000        0           Floater code
(3,0)   #000502   052        v
(3,1)   #000003   003        3
(3,2)   #010001   101        .
(3,3)   #000002   002        2
(3,4)   #010001   101        .
(3,5)   #000004   004        4
(3,6)   #010001   101        .
(3,7)   #090909   999        @
```

Answer (score 3):

## 326. [Bot Engine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bot_Engine), 14700 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[?630=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\( _7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<['4o'6o@<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461*  prstd!\0k:4o $/op>asequ+40[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8 4?4920C05r""Hadisptext在ｕR 8    
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ5G3qdjdbJPv2lUA0ugAUgGoCVegqgASazQ5Js6u1bO@sRyM75Mf4ypr1rLyeiPFO7KzlHXsmwt6PE4755B/QfmxsODasf6A952RWoUACJFseR2xsbJGoyufJkydPnjz5bhle/2c/i@DDnjmDWW/gjNnY9Mas41pnpquyBzN237C8nJ6RJAy17fYmQ9Mee2UpwjTGvLHhjtnAsHsTo2eyCLjqbG7vWoOx6SaZZ5qsZQ6cc/DPMGab52zfblsdgMTGzqlpW29NF/yyjD00B@@G78as7QyHht3x2Mi17DH55hh7ZoClO2mfMqPljV2jPbYcG7zyjD23B8aw1TEYBR@5Jo9UYACqfUpxFn2KjD1xXM@EFJy26XkOOpbA0XAt5/H200@vhNfS7FMDkBoNzOmV5DWNvbBMt3M1hs4@P97bu@qaYZ8pjs32rqOkZdn2ZOzsj6/Cz7HtnmkbTFdLqn7VMw/EHJuDYrqYXvACvz3LhdI0RKmV5yVjT4Yt0wXiiyI8t8Z9FSIcO5zgzLEHM2ZOARjg2IVg5phZWFosl05jSPg/MtuO3ZmDBycT4ABcczgaz5jCbEfwAHg5LvNGRttUOubAGlpjs8MGFmDndAU2HoMCZ6fm7NxxoeAVzoqEiDcy21bXwigiB56EzPbQbE16zJmMRxNAz2MdyzNaAwjWmrGO2TUmg3GStcAPiEfu533TFihZdg/z8WLughBsqAIc@3UNaGMNBgzQOUV0MGmPbaLHObpj0JZJWJodBLU7JxdAMgaen/vFhBeSwXjPXKfnGkNg1I5JNPh8/xnz2o4LNvhhWF4LbgLTNsZsc5NFd58@jLJaQEbVbUkBSavsgjEW8T3ZmTGYmB4bGjNI2x5D5WIOlZ8fQ4LgLLoWLbNoJsP0NMtmWRYqW5HpuTSDKlECA9RaPaPBL8/0IstqwPe5aBLT6bpGzxqYHErPGXQRUAE5Vs8xHd7pLMtoxWiSh2hTOgWWKbJ8gRVyrADvEivpkBBCzTKtlINfHn4ApQRYaPDLZHlqAWsgS0E22A7rGkNrMOPQRyME32Y5jRUAIqCqAWS9CBBKOkJYfMLwxn0gbt84A5DKwDpFkWEGUgNLLAWf1MZGisQWykeepNc3BwNMFYgFZMoVWQFSzUPGs5Ay0FIv6n7me33KPuFVSMMPcCxAjotA4jRQK43kKsAP7CCKdJA5OggYHWSGroG7DuYMQoVwefDLQ3nlsz50vUO0BQkLcTUkJgoVDWkA0aAQWAaKIs@yUMQZLOJchgGegEAhz0CuFDVWzLJigQG5SmkGpNcAGSx/DeSZBkhoCAyKVYNy1QARDRhGA6BaJsekEF21DPpD3AzEBRJoWYiTBTOUi5bHH8SDgtcgSQ3S1PXSnL0ANz0HmcxliO/0PBReAfyAWDrgqgO36ICtXgR/jFsEwhWRLQs@IYzBqG8gLaAEkJmB1YAgOcCJYEN4MOuFDGcpCt0yx1abx24RB@eRyfNISoiaxizCN4sUBXTSAAYZHLKgQ2lnsC5IlxJUS96EhkWWL35QhIA4YgbDFhi4d856sUCExkGiLUq7iWcOgAVBCLUNMCPPg7hA0ePDscYqCmpo50znDFtikh8LyXgkY1ouNsMg8Dqm6zIMC621lyRp5E1anvlmgo31HK8uiDcTJHPXsAYBAlTvjDE1JPCNepDebBHtrusMqXIOUdoMHGe0Qm6DbDtHQI@cc3OO@lz0GaPRABoEcDeBEBNjAMicG6RQkL4RTpUjBJEwXrtvAUBKCgSz5Zptor3IOsTOgAhfRLHM9Nq9DEJ5EGpXMmzkgFT2MI49GQzK0F6abZappTrmWQpdeNuz2OYgDn5rBA2qANEyQBmg1hixCCDd01Vq5479kvWc4WLWuGzaD7Let7ANGZwbMyi9Loglc2oMQWVhqBfY0PIPgWN4CWJJeLzl2mcdx46OAyjnLrTPkOkgJwByQDQZW0MTFDoHomCJZwlplIyEWWsGrEzUyqqkz3FMrhBKla4SijtkQw68skDL2Jm0kWqYtmUTB0GL4lFzVwO4XGtV0QD11TWNDg@G6gliFFKwoLk0gehCl2gTIFRxTNsDdclTmYV6JTB8z@kCj1EbD7oKRJ2n06a8Y84Dp6naViWiNPLN8HTALNYejRi4g4IDaO2li9BIO68t9hY8B32PDdoT152x6QgKwBpCqHHb6XaBad@aoz6AYMMOa8/aUCshl8g0UschAdQeXclyYFs3IYxtQrZ3nn2d9UygNjTpXcCUOH2egdGIskCkMGze3NsGUAqz0B7NiCwAJojRdRwV3TuO6RGPgDoU1HhMzDN7VCOgenXnMmiI6gswJ6gUNrAsCBxRqxA@JigtzQwmJQr/U9OGGtMGZoS6DsWHCu0260LnIdTSo3ZotNvmaCzYwyEpZtkhjehgDzUiclUEMNXrS@v3QZlbwECCoJLPOaHm3zgl4Yo9BVLUDBSxoocCCoFtBjow4wJlMLuWPIQ4u5K6/ArDLGDwSl6Bw4hqAqqHJBsmY5QgKBStdh9F4BiFDKkoUMncyfXsg1s4eXfIlG6QNmKjgbSR1FTghHishqHAb3AdkDoaIKzaggMGXXC4BbThDZdAdgIkB52wq5oyVJCFtwEdOrazBCoQM4CLQRZ9qCyIGY9QahiDgBmpungLZYRyet55xvYLms7RyHGhZnChM0NJxossxF0O7@jEgiYiDh3vxRYVWoootvPjMe@0jQbQkaIqhjUVlFEDJAUIMd6FAJnn8BRDCFOtJ1gCv3OS@JyZoAm1bRP1WcOdcSCQPWiVIaEZs1wXxOAZtg286fHbEJX4FJoCo9NByYrkoHp/NXEVOXpn0rKmV/spbXRUX3vSmeGyLnZRXNA1oBLFol0vGq@QO8UMeckpZzROUVT@liEgBVKhyGNd6PVAQ7AHguZoZrdj8kIVk5NMnoy7RTkOBozIVTP2VWM0vorda3BDphmeQr0mW4X1oNVWFHgr6EaYoEdKRQ/DBfUCKiGo6KVSp2WwdyA9XKZMdyg26pT01dRskJZpd4K0BCEQl3B@VZ6E57bJoIRaNcwBBqecUyOxQMA7UoIiyuCQSon2Ex1IyeN@pM5wx4lN4wssxjWQOLsI9HtoAGKEjAU6h9W2xk2hpdy75@sra9UqMBsoUSA2O/Fwz8AfiFFBUkNglZQQkYg6do7GWDdiccgvBr7k2IC2BJxarbGLcd@FGkf2SwkCAVklGznZJ6wo56fW6aRztaBtdMRAMtY60JWs9liuSND489pQvYmq0QWqQs8hilRF5sX4BPoa85IrFqgsgrmmh1pvVaASKuEYYiB4dSmJeFThNmfonVl7IFQCboLKzqVRC9A/FV39QBAlhU7gV9prNZUDwerA4bBn28ePqqIucs9Uy7LLCw4Dp20MyHkdg8t@3Mf7Dw63D7/eXAJjYLXKVx1SVraYx6Z2MlV69iSVVfXyehjGHPDD5s2wMeJiGFkS3kxxpiFVadaGxmXqk/Pg8LOrJAFNCMlBKYAZf1dUGh4GlC6pZXj9K40w6yUSkGQQxQ/LlH3mwwwMiDr6Gz4@zyZv32LhXUVqJNwRs8HE4AB8x9S@7cdT0fOKAuZ7tbq8RaS4oIVaNg6gzk3hkD4@n6LWfBUZUqVDLPPpwd7uYZXA9g3v1BwMFAqS8sagSxluRwWeH0w6prQsDIg/MLVZQp0jjvo04bqUwO32AoHnZctWwAcA2MVRHaYMhn7WvD7gvnM1b@SqtAMOIDtBuKpXhvWh9sciGsIDm7g29nSXtaLkMW@sAqelLVbgu9hstXM5s5AthZut9jzNThjokJRiy/H1Rhe8Tj0FXdS5FinUaoH@0eNriHukREJXQPEx8wZMpbS8gYS9F8ViUS@1Az00Z2CqL0jiyUyOp1JRf@RUbXvU5wyF351a41g6zr9aHMJC6tvb@/pDP7AY5aMBDOo0YBccWya3izMVbQ94xHYGTs9hGxCHa4d@gqA2rczmds@xr5WQgY6Y1QhOfYD8xfEaYwRtjfWWOo4UK9xd5dMmhu2dg5TW8hkkElGIQKUovPraODOAXPN8H@1/YxcaES2XTgfmND1AglAcIhea2iFXcmAKJKQKfJZmMJgGuVbbfQ8lNA@BmRaCLoi4Pfde6kgSU00tDb8Upa861yj@2pldYS1w4awFhhDJ9p8@e7z/dPfJ9hcnYz2XW7Bn06U8EA7Sa4EupPY53bC2bvCqidlCcBGoGy5WL5ACE@ig@OPpE88Fwa1iEJUjsIJr@ARS7KtO34568auZOUdf5bXd5iz0BCsfDyoiQke7M8DOiMvn3bA9R/7pj8cjr5xKQS3vT1oqdFpTr9vOwOilKB40DINBSsOuy/4Bjmt4y2IAMt7M5DH4mBaoDjMaODQGQwc6LzSXh6KBxTh4GqwaWL0@9IVxws9042rAwZSbVAd6CNBXTgV5IwFMNqCt@PrlJHPW/oqmFzlfa2k9m5L9YAvVH8KudU3oOsWgtQJSxK9Y2cm9k3tsBlIaIV0FEmHqhpjzwbZgwECRpMFS7Of7xCFpgcOkKCuIRm8mOIgLUiqVS2cLWj6Xgm4ZdNNAZ1VwqE0ZGuN2Xxk7CsBTnC6NG4S4sOu1DburbgiDjyzofZ9AVjP1lycndgMU9JN7hBvOpNVnjbrWiFfY9SgbIny8Aty7kD3kXd8BeJeMwJr0ZSvkWce4Ls46BtWuDkuNhyPR5igj9mQbFKm3DsjrjhmuexghFfZMbSyETWHg96klA0IDjCrhCymVggoFLS2wXgrxUkDpRfUQOAfkVigCm49m8Hzw@euQHMFON/K95UQ9GuhHvQYHSb0REJHGmNsopT0cHxxD6xhwPkppKFwU0uzcjOLwueHxQUqIJGYt/fjQVwsg0GB8MBBtB7O1wAQUi7rnIDmAr3C0tD8fZcROP3AaJEg44eADaBA2TRr0QM5AZJ6RbZ4RnhK5LGbp1HbObYTWMllRaVljPsbvTFycDbQ64bxB8IzOwwA0ylxIrtO0Ycts81FWHplyAZ1Agw3NoYNDCaBdkSgwKQsGn3LEvqCHA9VQrdIKzroAfIXd3wEp1jb5eJEyxE4UsNQui47d1LbyjZShvAVuvkG3wsxvh2fAqdCPfQLQSGQwBU6jJGIElLQTZ0iBXtB4C3o@8NVdaTQb9yHHwGGyUXVGpn21z8d7hLF4hSZqo1EQ@JYdu4iura1Fy9FaNAmmLTBtomkLTQkwbZFJIROGU9FEMZJkQt86xUC3RvSy7kOexhvIA1PUHN5ao5hRL5czjaRR18RXx28cigIoD6EV/ACcaLxaRWM8LtfOcaoG9PdQ3neQd47arjUSJPgqKATcLmiQISJA9x61edesYN/0ZooMqy50Gk1UMWNu9KSePmmcXJx0EieX0STGjleMKvQPQXiNY0O15zqTEShu9WxZAdkWr2fKjUqrGk1HN2KxojKAhIx4/JNiPGFwWseiJvBU7OQkCiQV1Km3@y7Bmyb1eDwgFODRtaCXMRjEoupFEdJvxRvxRBTixqNJEMvVaBTo0kYieJRpHBHgTLRnTYGUUDGhiQvPKZCApDkprK7fMEf9mRsOEIy6gZaNI@jz2XyoDCTFw1LyLY8fVugWevq@3svDgXKLg3eoL41mXLpLHNOT1MLKEr/dPVO6Q2dspD5XodOkhprL6Fo0pSjQEpIPh0TZfmJ5WIUN23QmXnikcekAKKYOrsf9CQhLf9lNErjKGklmu@@w6Pp9gM6CaR5sSnDGSuHzXj6ATluFHwpR1EpwsgS0C1qPYoFcxLUqfFRGIyS46PHH5nP50Rs1SK1CcVgaE7J6tuOaCpAEYki0eoTWGkk1Jpak7NPI17V5CeFLTRp2vC0TJOLewDGItlxch@aDRsNQfOifQ5RDsyMNQH50QTyqvCxcs5PakGhy1nH70EJAblAS60FpDYVHyvFGHXU8hahSDBvcsCfv3YHSec46uq7n27lu2fdDrgBi96GQsFdqQxfX91I08IyLQt7lw0J@H/3pwcNdPnZCjS02rziO1hw6nQnolaLfdGjavSTbBX6ybGdoARn8@G9PB4eOM@a9fLCsGpnhnWZrOBkYNOZzdVjmxnhtp@UMaCjopqjz8BPXMwYGH4Tyfbc/fwK6/vPjo6paDgVKGWfDG9PGccjlyXJ67ofnHGma1Z8e8jhjyus5GdstfzUbihnhkUePiVjLBmXkuxfQ3a9SOIci3IvoPsR1bKAri1EEsgaOImCJAuLaNlwSJBwvtPQluq/sgwXhNArHFcc5theaTu5n4253wTlDzqcKiqbB3DlLznyN20IfMYxSjgfCBW8LYcKA8hQmWPd2NZwQXsESg7458GcQD0ExwVkyaNsHqD5B3wQ1cb74zARFeoSTISShcYqNtUHX9K4NW0CdGik8tBRZo3oCbVgKNRdpPcXEEHeFaortiKlJj0tPB7r2NHqyWeMT1th1cnmvLcUH39ebAGKzVvGXIq0KhilFo0Ewgkq4QQzKJk3bX8tqsAjDozF1iaJUJC8FvYapnlZOpoXdRsojInSZfHIy/SStfwGdD1w0tn4v1TMrmNxKapGdj0O3@yA2WGK6SDIoh4nddQYdhU96Qfkz3l3CghBLDYJlayTwwcVy/RVrFi5iESsLQVyGFrtdg3ul6GrXA4SWxwWAoDZcsHenybN3rA4t2JnqjQbWuMEu1bHT7GPmxxPXvrqQjquUrmvMPEmsVKmy7cNPP6@nGxyCNDRwIqvIS2vqr8MEPRj0HlzuCiZcbzO2xtSw08ICC/OrqYDUlOY8AH2AwROosCAhkSNE/Z35bp6Xrgkdz5iJmHuzYZKZ8Uu1OzDGY9PmvMVnE1eTm0/7iGSqlPyWmEMoszRNtICiaaEfoFhhR8cPdw8PVeBQLxbdxQmZMlQ7o90HfWNVpn1KhjNfZp90ouwTjBPHXrgEVQo6E00RH5i3AswN3QlIHUVBz3Rj4BjHuZQ2ONP0FUXkCpcgEK6aao@JRgGwmBmHPBGw8lL8n9u85yTwLLMoSxAlgdyxe2WgrRVXJ7b1RvWg3SA1FIJEed@T1thW12Mkvta1OPGPaw1xLhi6TKQFQh7qdbYG0o1Cy6z6nr2sp5VSI7HOGo0Kn@GHiKjT05pdsf7TEPTk02EkIAXO@6JX1r2yCthPgUZuMRbHTwOelQTfArLupDW7XkvldV2OB8gqb8GBe8pXkVyySpWj6C9tIhFCK6EWVzQtrpcKZes5dbKvrC6H7PgIBPnBacgYzyVbqzItHvcx44BeGC52ncvsmeN5VmtAy1@7A4uvBAsa67IgjIDkUyacXAUrBtEN6zPUMyyM@ZpnvpJYUIL8qaGBnhTmjBxicXaBxCRS6khF9u4dOshsXWfEBjIuOeb0vfT7tCAfHzuA7GOxhDqsc5DQEMtTUHScSLLfeVuc/0Uf3jFInV3ReZUzORyP65yWferQLFJgaqZVLYd6ZhB7eDq4HrNreX16LQQNcOBh9VXYecNWl15LAtBkipimJwcaphcaNhSnkTqkD43YL0l5cWnKQrItszuxezSniWamvLklpFIqUuBuq2WtCgpEwNVm/ndJMJCVWPN0Natqfu3BAR5oFkF@8j7RPOtXVzWxBbpDIzWGWOL7n7/ZAfpfL50@tFc4nhkYmqApYEkp3ZWFJaKihV7LC5YPu08GlkGEIdNtINuGC1kyBoFhOWia2lcU0DeGOFEhShx4E1@gi97AZhxzPs/of5cnsmyqzga53V4V9soqL54UTSpBd7FDROA6l2VSJBKyvBDMKZ/YCXXcUeDejpS/FIsRM/Ny70/GE/4GdfjWQrRG@LupboqQ6ZzR0kzokBoty7yhyF3jdNJxlNFpL1CL80vCznNPM8sKaCVikrmJxuXZ5xl0rR409/53VbB5@5o6p89tXOHZE2@ktKhv3@E2qgjDG1JwB/y9KogltjoFhtVUswb0uiMnCujAKGKNRQpXsCohollXyDwwWjNUhfofz2XBegWQONV2IpHOrJiwHo1Wx8f@KcUvlZbHnqptTo9lIw8pvkpW4WNzlGGxbvaWUoXmyhoaA0XvhIwrhfmy5Q7XggYzpRTHPMN5orOlJTenPjZI7cnAcOemG1h8joc/ObFqnFs0G6Iut52B5WGFHqySmv6au3lauE6ZXqF1FdYySnagI4rtuBKYlksBpz3Gtagr2OoOMo2vAcWVtiE@UZ1VxGo75/hbqUH0oTPM38sbtbdLsbqDfFIG7YEBTfnKFmFh1BFHNW/h1XPLM@m1nLCnSxEdtwdL3RdrgT@eGB4fvI2zPWvgeOyI3jcRqOcCFfh7OU@HaWkZtkKj7GHzDWLIXzwxL1Bj0HMG@WIvZcBrZalP3C6KfvG9q5ALhJSm3SKkfA3IsTXxXSnaT1Pu6W0FRJvHXFw4GzLe0Mouk1RiUmd17qBvgDOCy3O2ly5STDXFxxBXJIxzOefGzP/@HK3HKtL6rcdoRho1KHgYoVQEw9jlWvbPk1r25tQ6dxNK18AWbstEqHBPBya0V/S@VqRMT2sfGUNLp@8uorqDiTkxl/Y1DlqvTdyHfEM/4@5IpUU21sUUAM464J6XINRb0Tm8E9bYVKPtRmFiQK/dvF2bWRRqI1DAR9h7fgaGZ2i4HqNnT0YLpbrQQbMPbyZZf@RXaaezgB36fKwcKt6iLC2o6J5Jvxs7TbyThyvPqtl0Oi10mNBUzoLlps5UJoj72uLvhYTJZZ7yPCxO37kh4/I0iCzhtY0rRZC@qm9PgUullG3Z5niG7ztK05bjDD6mpECodizUxkC5pDW8N5XYNXVH7E5h89ELD8c8Wt1V4xa8tRHdS6AP9ptvKvTwXNOdSlPB2dQhznQtWm8ewQnNXN2WCu4Hx2Ehvqp3sFqXFAMimlpUCzfWOq6hOi1zYPDPNJ@9CV5JzdwIb1FoiFlgnDXmc8XzOf7IFaE0mgGxrA50VPrm0CTrDYq@0Xk98fzPykBTB3@rvKem2U5Nd832qgAjC@SCje@FyemQsjR2bOhijXEBIXZVBrhEVbiuksD@dOJSIu8PjZ7JD7m4SVLOxyxwmQ7v2c2Ny0cvynxpThuizUeYV7MEVKpTc@b536UAn8zaUK6T4e0jblcqfxuHQe9Q21etjb3exNp9p2/3zT5fkB7YVlUO4McxP5TkJtQB614f18iNRgtr58P0HDiDwV3oiaKRC0rH6S7FaRd31eKWsI@COzNa4CE@t47fGWMuO9Cwstb0zQm0S54zdkamQrZVQQc41sPfq2SoP/v98w4i3djVB4r4358X/q19y57hjEcj@jRHg4lHL4qq0Gbo2/SmLl/zQqstHbenvnWGLVU4qmJBDE26LxcxLWvc7uMmdM7ZZs9ptfvWbUi3TGNsW6cpf9SHW@/Ud0XKWEx5iM7qwALyujMV@aUa9j/Cz/6qQhcDSLxZCww36CvLBulov7cyMk7bHh8QRRMr45hwqDbyXeFl2k5ffjOxxnOgoUVSwQgvn5lAwyrcxbKMlZoVbb6Yi2GxXGMll5KSjgq5YqZB4dFWji8tLKALVbFMhr9WIRTOJWEUWvDyMeQWi4pogNAKDd2C@wJ/LayGWtrI2f1Jz7suMPmIfQdUNHytHragRdKhUWtoswxbfFaRWR@kcPckfJugc03MG6dVcjfOq1A4baAYjgWfJnyg6CYrx9AG1sjjb6Z0V87GiUVS0Be/OmXIaTNb3pkWBdMxu3wWBE23qYhDh@ZpQQdR2jinj4PoKMy54sUFl@30QKgrAzYP7IddpbYsXX@0vPiDNlP54qnZM3AR92NrjKtAl3AFseyydUu3wv7axPCsr00gZ6uYDY@C4DORbvjMALQtgffE6FntRwsFESApCCyWkPLPAvuj0/WyOO9bHq6hCgw3DEwhy3EmRq5rQr9hScirQ/fBKRjzCsT3Vy4NvWx43RnNcBvajEw3jaxbYxplFd9VXcdVq8tuROJ8MhxNPPFZjgOt0gqPQg9Pyd07twC48gZEK@sbg/HykerQkCtoYaJRnBtXaePfsAZOj32jmGagtIEShsr5EsZ5AM3zM1wa5NpLOJHSvuPMJw50KC7P2BsoWzPDFMu2xjeP5ozHuEzI/2JmeMuBWx9Sj/Gt3v9YCMrxcoo8vl3Xn@95vqV9B847ciZu20RjcJBJuFsgUjV3/GXNuFXEwYNYzsO9tBtnb6A5dOzJWHEn9o2tQv7GVqHMpsV8iA1Y7Gu7T57Hw9xAy8Bv00JN6PxNvMFsblq5ZuAKk1k2KGKr5ehiaL8v8ZCfu3RIa5BvibONh0O1SVw/dJb1d57NXHN85w4TCP/J8KHZxpnDW9N@6jxxbAdaoxEIyuGhyQ8TWFjrsTwiRnuM2@WBPp1bkzkisCsaIa5tGCOzBeU7mJvu0hZxwA@NsbGiKaKxQer/BaZbecUatEz3NQ36hcyrurSLCD0yp9S3WM0wvA4q43abq8Q4HrdQRxZmbLyR49j8TdI2DR/tyc1SBZoCet19rlzFFf4L4wJL@2eLWT044wtFzA4/7WJVXl2z5Qz4@4ZlSbbFlwUYrmV6qcd4eAK55bNMAe3Lu1GGFG6UIfOuEWiyZ4ZH8/TLuxpzkNr0I1YB9Q237eBMmDDcsEAndOLBLWI62DTA1w60gPBTkFhGeyIObrwNrcGwNaTXyg5DqDQPzRZuN2rRMSFjY3q9MPnIkDgjIbSoKzhZwBdXWKnzLPYMeiPx25uthX7UIlWtEb1IUq@cLqf1Ooptme23Bo6aOUSv@dj0gj/kOfWUjCvGqkPViEaRUwZtoV9akxZXr4FCMzCVcd@FPn9qfNPwtn9@y5L5kMnQxEnmxVmYlaqr4/Ups87y@fRAuLqmIs4OBFkSnCPI9UNle6XmieDh/@DBV1PQCDfzWf9MExBdt8/gA/IT1xafu3DgM8cbd63pAeCN@w5WiRPMVg6iwIfXDDRtrMoElJ49GfDRh15o6dWwQ90xhQ7AVZQBieuxqZj2mUInzE2v58jhu8lS23iS6tjsKOKABZxpUB77G8uCYOK7ZAI1LBtxvaeW4oSd5rNiBegy4p77kgH0LWesjDz6pkbes/3HB8fqyNOWtk/bfdyPcU2PWzixQS@mQ0NSrw03NN/JV6R1LG@cenCkKTuP91UMsILefEZDgQ/OzC18Vo57inNLjZSxsheEvuZ4uYL46PjJ48R87yeL7fRdZ2jGw947R0dJ3Nvy1aOl3uHYe1A7us50ZfT9XU2LL2Hf5zbNDq6SnktSWgXp2ITeKDDjI37gy63KVdsZmZ3j2cj8HBpPlODeHZPPr8zkU@PM6mEtZKWVhKKKykpqPhsPLc6GzrbpBt9V5XlqjVBatumT4p@Vy1FQc8ik3Mxy7eGmGf@rWgxLi5UIHxdJS1/n1rGlQM3o9dGUMrx/KGKapq2i85HRhXJluZWFtRhg2fzwwDm7w1SyKTovSuCkjIGrFOvWpeQFZQiiO4UvHJ4XjmBsrVwGcxOAwDm/tMKfm/bMsBWay7pJvShDbFzUdmOQb5h3mJAKVvic4WnSS@f4glX1LNYmY/yWhI/dUJSdnQf7t0U4FLS8OdSnT5@zZ4aHp5vcHDCMsXkHjOea0WsFx63waL2V06kdF0DpN8LrjZbX5zI7MtyOY8@mt0/C0eZWbNrpsOIAFtookDmwptaytqrNx7WeLV9mdFvafB@HM1vQg8On3ghAH77zzzUtnaYzjfCrpbn1lpLxKziLocmY4UF5Ya/j/UA0tFFvUcEhvrQ3@tic4nIUPhq8rFO/tH3L39D2FeKrm5Ob/Io3@GVvSO@aHzqyjJrWbgCYu8GP5dTA@7EzOO876o7hmt4dyySE2k1ZKt2QpVJITr8tpnE4lKYYhXm1so/7GMRnKd8em2M3O@o7LSt7S262u3iiJXuCB7LfWslwQxktfuk5Yk8Ity/H4Xxym4R6Yrw17yKbTm8XoGZ/Qjsq7r4wpgWas2n3LH78I3vgjHfJdj0zfO/a4cQOn6bsJcV5GHzLKd8E6Kn@kdexmJ1IxOOLVzKEtzzyzX545h7fpwdh371ja2I7HngEOxTFJkA8mgv6BiZunZUIBO7NjNnVqpYrsS28GKEMLX@cUkQnOgDJT6vO1i/E3rpyWbvE/YVyWWZi72Nwnik/kxPg4mmCkCemnGpsfQw@6/7OPEanyrN3jHoToL5ouTTY1FR4q3RFbFkElNYvnu0/2z063j5@flRPNy7luNiYy3GzbUjN37L9SaYjQ94F2UBK8RN6aWvvAJKjE@@xF@L5@WKQsytZqy5kbZ4peQvjrF/YdipFO1RTyiXgp8g8NfIFlQOdOGw/x1Q@YoNxmW/sHBBJ5XUOWqY0oczKLL0s4ZEBtWvdFv5XL@wgX5bJoC9PWByqCrzcc5yOSNEz2e2Pn@Le9v7j54e7zEdwzjTnVmfcr5Zy/MxdbMkVE8qpa9FilyqLiihRKKtqNboXBcJE1Sgr075gOu8W@ByC@dTBHcUi9gaLrRN8oGA0KJTUf/5m6jKq4rrNOISN@khFmaA8BmDHuNfvz3/c4efB@yd8@DfTuENqtugkBUns412xixcpShVztPp@Gjp/nTbsBge/z@/8keg6AODKczqc68rBTXE6S4VfNiTO1fITIgbxz5DGAUA8I8v12JmFu3U5Dl08smqRlXHNAB3TprJtvHwHeJ4ZdCcBoD6xx/xYGHGIRAT4SA0ESpKtE7L8BgM5FDC6uQas3DJBojHPhl6VOS6z18BnOMhW5lvGFaUWvRbFB81vXVL64@EgFPDaGVde6mSc@vCr3031KgzM0/QDsP2ysHXB/Cvc/DKFZX39HKx5@mEk8Ow6gTVPPKA50jt0z5DNt@bPiYXHdfmSkllDKJozojQG5ynwtwICdg4nVv8cCgpYDEpJbMnn6ZluI4aH55VTKWQjbJVVWoZsTvmaoCuH6OVz@ayWAiSVMx8gnXrdw/2OHGA8XgbGl86sUfVVC9hrc5PJqKSb1XyFl2Zq3X6ZkV8FiK5DWOm8j8jVGcSBKPMY4FcT0aA5SWhxjIryKKpFURR1HGhnyB/bI7TbghAyiwGxOI1MPEZ5ihdOjd2ZfxhkCy9xCt2IsC4AKRq0MmSKy5LYRf7UGQPLLOyf57vIcU0cb9PwlDWPX6hGZzAiD6rXa9N886N/9YKoXyrWew4qk77aPIbLVn6BII4QRFlexrL1l@xkfGI3Upw3GbDpDwXLhpnZBvMvpXoreJbne/v6CXyxq@fnIbHY/SPbwd7IHmSGxfSUnklp@fg8S9ns0iyJHIlkIDt4Lsg7SA5EE4iJtmm9dkbe9s7u/lcPnh1dO2WOQkavBgNJXttMnChqst4IDNFwthaL5MFe6ujJgz2/IOZI50MSGLQXkRPtppzMBxkQ5HzR@tWsLcPwau5WY/yC72y9im9Gvwk1inQNDy39EenSwlFlj7Z/XE1cLy6jVi53E0pzeKkQ6B2@d@8aqrH4xWW9sVk7sSPR65ywpCK8jKgbWAnAdOJtrKeQ2a9nDjMWXHx4jDcueeG6mFleF@X1DB52hLuHx87p/Jgn4RDyCOXXTwZEpKSm/KAra98B17rnh5Hp/GJGfixS@DCYEML59E0UD4E69u94RCkyP0pRnCLYh67@wGpJ/iE8/DRB/9Cz4CBBfoBOLC6JA/l5wjFx6@O0PFVplUgsjtKOYCXZTQcT@vDiElRo1NeeTaAD9swZ8QOaaTbwoembDh0Qvw8nfFmByb46GUK4Ln0OTRqZBcmtQGSgZDRAletPICXEuYTTBJ78COnV8XRCkXF12MnFpnG1b047Vg9keyyeBIn2iaY1WHB2IWaaziq0ozKV2bwUbqyKn@KOzDDZP@oAy@kcAaNuqJbdMaex6Hk0Xm5A@ugePX9xFo3Ly3iJDtIUJ0t2rp6oGaBf0G6WJMZY1E7/uMpl0qJUui4lwO0qYH4UlH87TKmk9j2JLvmqoi5@NHYfgxHUiFh3aIxYbGLz47JURtbYScxO0vlCSo2fuGezRIK6SPAhD5VRzC6ZePsdM@wZi6WqwATo6tkd/Ly1RqyuqWoDzJRInK3jrU07oHHh0TNxCXq1EKVMYKvIQtBxAIx4JVE5g0Mc9JfwRCCXDh1b4k2X2NAAloM0oVyz2j0WunxrUXOUS6WyKNBFqVhiwH3XxaGaArDX5JyvywN1xdEWQDPo0KpSZC7Ir0u8CKUb4Yg8EmdiADqR0CmZ/lEZDGDNz7Bs9138xXZtqCt4uk/5@fFesxhPySw4W6PnWh0cYOUHPQedNnE1B1TT1ELQaIX30T7FaHhoWpMf3oFneu1RhZGviNRImAxX77Kd86am3cj1IqIoBQiZxQZAbEBq@uDwdEB/qnuJ33Jh/7Of4W25cmxd006b7lkimktX4KVVcizHPlk/UZT1@lY@k67eXzeM8ZsTmRmp7MbDM7Pfbe33UieyzDIsm0ptRPc2nll6/uWb6WVGK745HWn5uvpm2pCL1eRpY8qePfviffN9XJ6ezeSTGGsWIoztHLyTtSx2ViPlAisx/C08b/FFl1kufa710uWozCInJ3gLrlyQU6l6tAH/5PUKHh6oXlNr6lbj/ft4vQB5ms7YSQRvlmQH99Gb@kk00qTr8SPLslLsZOR1OvBz@qzBr0eO8CeRiClMOCh17lYZTrvkNt02e73JrjHj7lZkgp@9sYj75BsvXrxAwwt62NvDiIDNIfpplJtGLsL0tP7nP1m7TF48a27@@beGKXMNPwf4@e7lEzQfablP1tY@efAgm00Cbbj52TeefX17ezv7MJl7Vs9tZZX02uaf/enamq5v6qm1hudpjWj99PQLWU9nZfXPfxRtPnv2Nc@rZf6Pb76vafgqwOsMSwafDNPAiO8i/DTUsU7ZW3hOuwz/yfy2EzIbaG5137LI2whwuRaZ0V8zEpTZGtNqW4X/8v2DN5FxpKanXrjwHUfeRPLFCDeCAWwZ33YWqUU2MVj@MjJLVatVMBb@y7@F@LWvAhz0mW3Cq5bzYeVnkZpSpSjvIrU8GDRdh3T/r29@M8Q8XExUSY3zn/usDo@cLejyVgOeDXo2JTzRTEmnUlf4Tyve0@4xZo/7Y9PBj8U/tolHSysV6HUf1hOJRENtKvCoL6nvrmn6CQgAtsBaNN5CVBJW7sLCbgGfCBfwexEhngKmIr7iZuFArMYdXlwN92LJU3nxj/0cSpH82n3zYa0GojBTy2zUEvSsnZTLnPwpVijKjnMfhESSRU/kKHvFHgtq1@R0UZeTyeT9JlqnSFJlGpkTkHEascgCZSNsbmNhpwjzo7F5mI8Nt4vPX/yvf/GDv/g@/f2Afv8BD3@zO1Y3tQHxzqDq1PgDX7nmyhcnZIEMp8vFcjHVvDyJbYCkahwyLf3pu2guEz0KuOwk7o9wRoKnVsMX/Qsbmeh7xU341AILhZhHuTmcT9QINMFijZxSP6s1FFScqkpdy@caCudHP4@1Eqvfh2KS9UJJbtT0nH4ARafJvOD66x5zItCDzEOkLXjW4I/@4QmsaziKvEZua74Phbr@rAXp3voAzLK2oWdSuU/yu7oUqddTDbMBiiyr@UDur5XXiuV8WU81b4DLKtedTNN85kXONK3darXetlsGPC2jbWhj475aUIuqvjkxpsbMGLcmrWlr3J60NU2KvK@vsUNeDRos4T8niVuf56raFEYyOPhTFGcakSL/CE9N0zW2AYI0DS/QHsgInTv8g3ywyAU8jfcb9fcbwCG1xCZVz0ZNEVjCR23ebySUy8s6mCsV8b9ZC4wVergJMte4TCQ2X9YUpf6yVk8AyJcCpMphqs1aY5M8grREYsJ7s8EgvcRmPZp1onnn/mbV2aEfxIRHaQDczQVc799PqGC6DwBq66BIxBOJdUVZQxleF7IKAjdqCT9TiEMMlIhNYIDLzcvaZX3z8nJzE/436X0pvuB6uXntnz7zZ0WYuT9gVKud1FO1k9SJYLsG2NVUDV3U1AkYavCFcNCMSRGomGZZimywjciIaYVMZEOKvPrw5f@Mv5MPX/4BtvGgg5WkSGoDuwYl3kOAF7Of2OwJf2ww48@3ogs6PKmho81f5MJSqVcqKyv8tHqtmI@rKAabTreJG0xV9uoJyDwQDUzWi3m5mdBmOotsyvkCCodfuPZEo9F/8kovFaK8I417Il95T0JozRGDoL@w7Pknv7DqkSLvIJ8g1jzGMy1FgMYRRalJkdrmENfG4Yi1gp2Dz6tfKM@3FezNGmOag2jznlp1f7daKtX4YPv6M2KKjYcb8Nbgf3fN8/BeUEzmAl@tN/j3@C3@vRnj33Eb/w7f4B87fot/h2P8Y09a@PfMw7/jN/i33cK/4yH@PXiDf0/G@Pe8h39SpApq/bqWHqTbaa2ltcBgsbTL0v10X@uA/tbUWNpk6Vl6xtJDR@uAyYS/NJisdJeleyxtp20ICL5gGrP0GE1d@PTgrwuAXPizcO1FS0u3GSQ0QC2PLphC8GB6BzI@fiLVoccqvzJBC1c1Na3mrQaezF@XG3qpyFQsSbVZf3USbeCRr3opy1ozc@3kFYt4oMFXIqmTkxQfi2B6toKH@F9eNpu7Tx82mykUbydPnIP5/8HBMGy98X944Dw5cIYO/B8cHDxhZi1xPwEV//79KggC8dmK1CpbJ2USJ75IiaQ2t05qGQXN@QRICR3dEh/5zCHCt7Z2IkUZKEbnFVK/KudnlfMKGQIrGJqVIIAIxg3gWBFqG7hUfP3tHJ6zc3LEFxrPX5wEJm5IvTg/wW4I9C@Df9Bvw9b/Cv/W/7v@nzxnsXoD1KnYxeVmjJ44/sXjF5cXl@Jdi8diwhLbhD90ADtGubisoZECXYCpHos34peX3A3esfgmB1jDNDZrFHkeEERAJEiT0uWv2H/dL6YtnhM8HN6YLww4OZmm0/FKyz@MGifFjHc0Pxuv0NVC66261vizH9GR41txCpTLViraBuMWPatXKlnfVihWKkXfsh6Lla4/tfSWlgd9KpuNxysVsGz5YNNgDcAWAaxvyQFU0zPaVO8rkYv9AzqMG8RELhLHHHHBEEvTmf14/UtULsv37sXEtbJb2/F79/RS@t27wGU0AidtwanZ7Fhus4numXfv5KZME/WlHNjTxXfvtHQpoUXjjht7ivcGQVIxRWOf6DVKteS4QIoCeDMtpc/x6BueMR67sbfWKCnjSjJPjtO1Hum0455Ef/q9b33rJFqtyopMrlkNAWAqLLe5mc/WavksmPNFoJW8fsFvuOklSlr8cj0lc3oweT0aEV5asRDn0jGK/tCWsq0aVHEPn4vLCJU7y@biMRCvcVDQLiP4x521Uom7Z/OxYqIk/qpr8RooDPwPe8OZRHajsHEfdCn8my59UCRXLsyqdlm9MMs4qnhZaYsrG3HjqXnvXqYENC2mKydSs/lw@3i72azKsoyNIrzQkYS7hDdFjdxonQo8V2rUMXeNk2i0XLlPzKEVcywSrYhwShRaCVYsEREkq4u7yj2PSZoYa1iTdPriSxKjTWvgGMFWef579nh7Z/c4qW8qLKLvbe8k9aPnDyIaWnNzO3ln0H64u/3w4DlEePZ4d/to99P9z3efPwN3j53PH18Ci/f8GzYtsZ@zF9Jr961hmoY5Mc3m@WRy/oa9tqymBYQdTCzLcnou88wmdDlGEMx/KvBrW57x@rXhjuhhH374nQ8//G8@/O73Pvzudz787g9@@uUPvgO/H8Pve/z7vX9TyuH7p1/@89/78Du/C47/AX5/DL@f/PTL3/gm/5H9T@D3n0JufyJ@oXD8JwGsX/7pl9//0U@//JXfhN@/FL/fvP771Z8s//3g26t/GO/7v3dzmO/9W/j9Poflh/3e73A3/F4L/zs83K/85odf/3f8/8/EHxp/98Ov/wm@hOWf/eaf/acP3/r3ul78s3/94dvf//Dtb3349nc/fPuf6h9@419r6fDr9z784A//@o9@/6//6H@g/x/T@/fv8v/hN//ZX/4vf/m//eUfid9P4PfvwPSTv/z3wLB/94c/xP/v/@Hf/fEP8f9/@ld/94e/9ne//D@S4be44f/@l/@Gv//mV//j3/72d//6J9/821/7yd/@1h/@9f/@K//nb/zHv/lv/@Bv/vtvoeNv/eSv//iX/@pb3/mrb/@Lv/rWlyve37nx/eUd3L/8R3C5O553gXOXfH2sy5c/Fz7/EGrMUwE@Ae7@pQ@/8YvA4L/O2Ifv/BiXT8Nvxf@PdY3C/Jjb/j9g0K/nGX3SYILfr334zveQRP8dkAj@A3p9N7As@HDLd@cWIOtvL4n0Sz/98l/8iGwRs1yjEWRsR4t6MbEBfY2NUkm0pWJwGaL84iK0AIBI6bsooRb8vouy7cMPv/nhR//0ww9/68MPfxlbMSVbSm4nFe3mpY3Q9Cm5O4TDgPm7hMOAX2D6CRpGURJfgI19ITy/@OILqfkuhev0778D1y/IiT@Me@E6fuHl@6E7Luxn71jYLIxpYVwXrkHKhAWmmiANYMNXT3IZNk0IhKY43odfcIdA0w0yTvFNrug9lfA1/58bpxJLYBj@4M1GvpEMIp5IghulHCSTmE59cpG@xLiOssFdaK6K0s2WGOZgOk1MoSMKBkghAV4PEqxarSYwYpXjA1aOWq3ICJVEogr5xtg8TrJZRBDTBwQFYlYTh6y5UZ3yiAmEV/PJkZDQ6VDWdDlRrD6EBKvThwxhIXAC@@pVtVasTmsI7j2nR2KaeEA4IbBqYlp7D/YqwYR4UuThe0ClWE0kakVMEDPJiyfZ5IWUo8xR3hMsIcoAvjj8u3WfsU9krSg3udqGBOOh8Z2Yh96iibwt8D9JbIjs0L9vpN8GEXyNkhKpMO6/RRriFlcaMQDAVRRVVRn8cHZwi90H7ykHlaBk4ZPgEBLEEcQBgQOwIZZFgso3QRZIP1Ld@OgHgWFm1tfXpUhNzsgHKpEO@uruaZnfTPOOd4jKTM6XZHQ2aXm5jwvEr1D661EctI8yDph9kuC/@/c32CeQTfrO3SSmJDJO1olwKJuJhKwD/JqTkF5C10ACPiVA7yR1WqVpqoSUTDKmViPoxw4ODgQS5PCyKiWAzfWMhnacV5hMJhGIoapJNZkUX5W@5KAKg0q@4quuI3FpfJHperYC3ZcKQycW7m5o0C9Fx/fv30Op0BqP8j70GJlY7qFni@QJDnyb8mAw87ch6NmSxLvLTMtnoStNN0jCE2dxicXYRlziq4E5Ev4Ti@rFYpTCAfXV2Ia/@ievETvg0GKkhoj6D@/BFXNx33PngO0cPHmy@/R41GgwyaTbPc3myHXapufF0G/76UO@IUAv5eOReh1BH5d1FDDSbjlN4m//4eH@UZnxTIsiiBFiFZqzEdksaVJkNHqxGRGrH2S8SsaRj/BdnuctppcyEDVSkyJtE3sUwEv4D7@K9MTrPXCm0BFPynJSy2P/Kk4Dqkz6ujNheMoZ3xINdQrXh6ubm0QBqXah0Ig2GqG08lKtJtYNMU2qHe0eQ4TjA6bpaVWqfcGmKiaoXEq1QXVg2r1xfx0X4MgnaTmUp/V6Ool/eiYDby2bT2q5QmNtbXChYJonVGwXuJLqEqwXCmbjK/Aw6SsS@wo4wQNp4PIoJtam7R9UxAIhPE8kxlcJyVoOqllcOoGC5uCkUfipjIC9oa8d@kmRtW98Y8xqNejkKvt7UgTERZ/5i2QUq6P2VSrnzsQ1ybfHWMf63MJLgtSO5Y0GxgzqDpAjcnl52QVI@3tMr@lk5TE6@L5sk0sLzJdTQ4rY5XL1vZYtSFm9XH6f0XUJHKTIy5eGUavV042LbEHP5rI5PZPP5wo6EK2UzeeKmbSWzqdzuq6VstlSsVS4ZDEoWcNQatWMnpH@/@dOD00mbI5qQM7N1AiMBhizmykDjC0w5jZTLTBaYCxtpiwwTmoZLb2ZmtQkJm3yI70Y7hiuymNziicIcje55pmDroqbCqoyJaDLm@KIzJqIV8PdGY7RqeK2UlxVH4tfSJ1qx2nT9WZSR205nZnqjWcDXH0/cNxqFFSrqO9h4Y2xuNmuWmcNdeSMoAnUc4VEXUuDIMafVkzqyY7aHpiGu5Ur54poCaZItnLp8rlld5xz9Ysnjx@Nx6NDkxb4b2VL5Y6K53bgDvutYjmXa9TrspyoUzINvC2R13JlbQ1qhml0FPh2HXvsKXqxAZE7llutRqNbGU1XtHImXZQug@xLQDjMU03CmAnMSxKJdyGqUdl2bKiy5aSRtC4o3@Vut3u5cZGYWyTjQuE2oMilYiRbF4G1ooTCldkkqVhzT3AxutCiXIj5obKs54pypV6Z2wt5udK4lO4PzY5l4LL@k/TF9Vh5EG0cagQSOmHSZdl1nHG5ZXYd15wHzGh5PyBH6HqArHwZJHeSxhQvrieXx0BAQ0454FR@gFqNlrLVQQw0dqEdrDc2/aPVkEN1XdEzSkZTtAz@32LQ8f/u4XX41/ENsTK6dIzbi5@CUIaGxGaPcYPh2GHHjkOX9j0w2ytC7PQNWrO34zqe9w8I88CwT7nXQ4uf6RV4PTLwtg5vaI37K0I8Hw1xJ6Xp/qNB2B22AEGq2BTgAbzcgeMsC1Bgz5@tyOWT4BRNIAY/RhOCH@5/@ug49D3e3d55JOXZg4OnD698ciJQjj3e3TsOrAXu60fNBSC@vvv48VWr@GQPnh92J46LP2nv4Hl2/gqccBuYlIVnMVDgTEDEC62ktuDY8RrLFXyDJuFC4nvQ9bonjLn83JhG4wu@x83ygoWtfDNjWTr2N74ZDAVQy2RtvmEW@4J0OIzQFLVCSZJGzHbOWSHNOs5gYOAlqN01cOwbuKHHRHVpQHf1YtLnjjvonFsdc016gnuHShre9IhISI8AyHDSppMYrLGER4118HpSnKloDSYmm@AVwCsc4YNOaHStXh8amHPHDyC1DIPR0pWPeyC@GX7GNzuMeRrkds1ncD24FJGMsREpVu7d0565UFNq6XK5Z9Z2p8Cm7DlUG8OdJYs5WW3Le0xtRljPqnuNERRVJpvXNlDVAv127SR9Ws46bD3ljGqGB81RIpuug4o47rYr0MrlykBn6E5noYnS0zvpnCvLjwxsN7AB@Zvf/vHf/@mvHTJaLgjSbyMFr4gmy7ikeU2TVNKr9VIxVyxl9GKyWCpmc1o@l0tqehK6JIUSaKVprajli7mSlixmSxlgyRL45koFKcLXi6U2CCR8ywDWbuPlhJukmqt90MH55BV7GzPiLGIE9gmTTYgj43X03pj2TG5YVWh7mJZmmQIDiAZrs8je3k56b0@WH6AFJ@130rLcQUuumE4XHsiyST47RdQoZIfHKeIZL/KYW9LpBzuyPOEA8HhUWe6jZTeP4ziybKFlZ3tvD9PpokXH@BDslPtwy8C3FCCYjZZMhgN4E0CDYNs8nSwhuosWTBJ99rjPDvjJ8qc@OuhzyINxAI/8nG5vy/I@t2xvo88OZTvHEf0MLdv0yLILFqgdstwDQ8@FeinLLTBiHZHlNpjaMwPc8CJIPEHTHhuyPOPkQQLJ8pRCG@1TWW767pjM5wKbHFK3TBaN5/o@WUr4J8u6jzQGywSWjCxnA0sW8vbo0edGf9wxe/yZufzbhpw@epQxrOlkd6/16aetXq/lzrZ3Pz1Er52dR9D8zyZuq9cSEVtNeByItfNIN06Hs6sP5Hq/2Swbg6VenzWbWcO@4tWcNU3EEGK9AczE08OEhs0d8Np51LxvLJtLJIBNFA9D@LbweTCE7wOjxb38h7zoO2215AqyP6rKdEs01ES6sDk5NNquU0H7tLrGWDQWTc7q@XSjQh5sCEpxunJJ10PH8G3guEP8YlafVtON6rRa0PkylG5MPpnqOUtOrg23tFKuvGZsaXo2MS3jfmynG2VRRdtiMe3exlsWexrf0jPZsnyytaXIda2xpWvFcr7wcmMiy/EyvrcyhTIETEeh046veL3Q2CrkQlEKhYSR0suFQrxyCfQYQ3vfwvGAZix2bhqn8Tiii71TyAK/nHpG@bQq3dg0Oa1yvNgsXplWtQo/NI6lr8Hq4Amlk/bYcTnEHoCbbqXLdP21rJWKMqSfSsXicZB3JJrgO1@T9uJrx6fHx19IKBBrotf8jN@pWhHWTx/tqNCRFjY8WVTdwy6J46o7KK4WfPjBl77TMYhd9RE0sNBr8d1wj4zrDNTdadscYb/G9/DPi1PFKV/q8aMFOEd96Irsic6QV6GjLey2yfDgVavDjGoNTEaHxQgrZsTPqWlv1mrVZnXIb7CuBbE@Y3Qq6RzMvsdxDzY@U/QL3DciPJrV9GWlVZ1GpgCnWWWK9mrodF7piXalg@etPqg@wMiVJnxbFbNq4j3eckSudLfsKmMT2zO65jPTxW38@wfroGjgZpJYl5nxdXZCt37voHZ/qdRcZs8xezoZxqDn3oovOoWsSJrY1/wsX9DuJpyfv6x0qyz2Ml55A1Z3ncU66oP4VrbSiT1gzTi4pF91X3WZzvLZCl2EGENIUImINnSbdrxa@wx0Iw74tFwGREQZnwJMTAnAWh3yMOIj67LSrg5YTGFTFifyZCu9ah1jv8PXpiLLDUWpv2tINUV5IdWgnlZmEaPqTVp0SDdLtzQ9na9MwU0rZCt9KFjj5bTiVkcT16wMwCqGkPgmLqMC5ASqAZi372IffvGb8U0lV@VuFQL1bgDqSFNtVqcVG4/9AZaoZqrgkahn00no9cKrkIRmXs8ntXwyk8wmlQK6QhufzCXBEXo@oGTEBjGZMTmZnqZVLamZWjKWfmV1XsWTpzFQZ4hkLJ4cO7t4iTi4QCEhV5IVvgaLJ/SNAYNScJixqRCbgqSoYMaA5n02spJ9BHVoGgOKEY8rLLMRG6zHMMz68WS0W2@Uy7vT0dfAK6a82conCunE23i8EluLV0EjkmoVqYZShXI9WgOeFaNrzJsM61DGYNIKerleb2EWC@lkJp2B3FnNd71NuSY3kum1vAZFdMlIPWJcYnAVaa7kzN2aqJAPTCg5raRXJJVWclCSWkwv6XEJFwuKmNJIiDWkJIudyP6GxVg0WtCj0Xi0gmPfa7IY7ARZRnIsCkI1ek/bkkH/kstySccAc5FIe9LSYRXsUkKtj2VLUuRCury43ITuborW7qFyuUYmRa3dlyJlxkAPPBGnnqTWGPvYJYGJzdpL/j3BNcYAV6ID@kAhpXU6poV9NPY57r/dYlFAzHCHdV3PNOp6AVoykI5@UF3XKjjeH8FVzGoNSOxdAH6biRpuXfmMzWZGQvEHoO8x1kusS5TpyNU5ve3qdu9wu@LbdnBI80SSZbkSlSMX0Uj0Ev6kyH3aL6Pz/TIsEtoxg2PaOGYM9HkfIdnAdi78oagyXhMTM8pcEtQb8fdPrcFFMaPw8QYQTZeXkfUUlYjYdlD57JWegzKyHX8fAvSRUC2HRiqXw/HYSOrVyPuGXsw82T@wH7p7JuO7EIrZplyLsLSm4Kr@Slm45vj6Y7lU1GX9NBlh9yOVCDtVolqZdiqMjkovCy@LL588P3h@sCdFTtberTk40s58qrD39le/Bl2LaCYbZeykGplWsxWxMKtWU7RNHY8TKrAySPWullfS72qce2vkkdfB58Mv/mZ2ulkEu57WwK7ruYReq2kbOotHRh@@/AM8R@Ji9/PtxyzqGTP293/6I73w93/6r2jBU/Sy4tG4cCECIdGo5QuRi4vRxcUlPNwvF2lEOFLZQhzMfP5Ai9RSmp6xbbvCyinD2Cgksvp9u5ISYbWCFo94SkTMhBRyEe@d8NLTRfDypyrISc5jCUR2D62crt3fRJ7Qgj1ULPjbNL0SMEXxyat3jIGlXev0epZOplSKld8rbPO9ssne4@zAe2WNvarWcHZZw51X/uD5Bu4wwRmkaC2R2ogy6OSwWv2y0kgwGn6H/uJL09ywT65w9Mkarm5fdNqw4c/c8OgPI/kOHlh9m7nx2pNjG/FUqtMRpw5tmixXA1bYSAFmJ/EPv/gbup7/@z/91XfNd80vdOgDlkp5TY/8TPvZzyDADbv//Q4czTLgNn00BB0/tuIGcejlShG8Vr7LeHi/G4gdP9QTrJ4NvXu0SWeo21ApNfmRUp0YBdvAzcFJ0pTpwJd4RZICjZI0YbfXThIMtoG3O0AtlS6kr6AXNKCsCoJT@socFDgMocl02k1vMHFHtOA/RvG0RpLdgyiQwlfwtK412tQspK8CAiu1cT0qR9kjqpEexIam5@HZX9BwSF@BKOIkPry02sD99xjSskHcqxiE8CSPTh3SbkDaAx6hSa4xyj0PkGQcOx7JBm1Z@gooAEQFC/QCZm1CgAqImK8AASAPMQHYarBNlomzCyuRqMwPFrvEldR4eprh7/2VMBpC6@Becz9yBcOBE2jpePcT8oUoYVDJQo4@EA6Dz/lWQc/H6GRDRYs2598ZFMCig3BilDV2794cq2rV6sQZ5Qjhn1ojHMOicrCX4wrA/D7SJ52ynGR4ZFvFdw3YDiieIHSB6xR@VlslFJXJaL2UJPi/M9MiR14pKvKoYAZEefFa0QaSQWQkOy/DNtusMk0vxFmAfBtwbxNSdExY0PE7mX6i6l/4npeA4c8i/snqIIiOw@OCgm@vbv5m0ABO8FhrPAKICwOxaZsf8oMCbX/sxw5iQVasAYXuWi50Smgy2j8xLJbR4hhtfsIa4UFro/UswyXKuTh@KBaGZvA18Gwskc4ane/RdqBAvZFj02FadPAHrv8GjgAZJc4k4mhP7HO8BkGUDUUOY@TReUTI@YgxHQ5G90dSXJwNbrnQc/Vpk2RmT2XtYYfpJRYjRqOzk@wAXJwiEcIt0HCRxq2BOQSUjkyTdud45VSqB/rRpEUHSD2xgK/6exa0KraXEld1ps6tUyt1jMc4K04XN/Hw7fgRVKmw@vGJZ3FY08BxTtnAOjX5cG9s4TADj4GOD3pqEig7/wFhy7iiQc8kWRq8kzwU/ArwKXBjMRmKuxabxa9/M9parIkl@o4aGcvFazjPDDtEX3reSaJb6808/zgUOtQD7Gogck1xEEI1ilucgxM@JHGwS5XOFFFxGmEUg06mfyAKGkH9Ns8YdlAlbGNAaLb9owWwFkNuv0INANU9qFl4NtrYLeOBGICJ24m1oeoJAW@zT1hGlzAgP61GnCwDMLDoq4vQwQ@iYj68cQcKRuVbyUCuQO0cdsAPt2IL9sP4Pnejmc6tm7M3WxPgsNGhtKqMVwvfkgtZsHYgP1PW18AzDxguwWQtJicAbEKOyxx0EP9qdM7tEsmSMrsOKckQgiA1QCFVwb@nl4XuK5DA44Hh8UM4xSlq5@fnKh3nN3Et1fTwDH8PLx9OjXoWaMdOamwOR@K2NAtvyRRw5yaFX92BV1JvTeky6NK9Gf9KUterinUhsWjXi2LjeIZH1PeGdAwQnr/jEUPtWXS9RTsmlqlw/tMbyQuf/8rIf0oxeolAGEMw0@Qs2U4CsGSrfZrsnncqwuOMKiQAh1I0fUc8QtP1LUPPN1mjbhDCGdNeC9/eGpzSlChAkvkw7DxpnkM/5My3CvvImkIk2zxn265rzGLkH8fQyMCxGak9bAbNPvmAEZoZdsHPc7Sm9VljIfo0iA6Nmt/5YS6e8SNd3AyUH@6J/lPuPwX/KfefzhP1k61PG1wlQ6dLzA5yPR4N54dEMDM/zCU/CHPuQ5BBx2YaB4EhZwtul/BrVym2T29ug3Ks@owBPDECgpuxVP3lSf2kYXvm@UYjkeoBs8tECChxAF1vEE3PO4EZqT84G4wcb8HJxhMBoVUSeKNTuy@4gfMK5jEoIGIMTi8LD3HrDcVSAq4QiAwDBNTDwBNVg@1xzIpXgsNkyRMYpy7PacwRqwtkGqR9CS/hBuoSJz0nbBhQIwQI3YMsAZrgw/yaw29s8aXDCxcvpvfDKnTJxBAPE4o2okDJK1WFy5oKFVIIK0Xx0QSyo7pavZoV3x@Kon7FK5TNS1H@YfTXPhr9LtSL5dgTw/IGoyKFqwouggMVQlQXoiqrVUPlChikNoyB6ULLtcv1U9FaQzIbKb@bwdPBLHjneA1tLFT47TgvH9r/JttyOWCFWbUKWZxVebXk9cInKSd4EM0T0WY@I4j4XIAAjPTSaKaINg1Hm1arXHCw6Ypo5yEkp4TklEfhoacrkGyIaNB7Cu4vx@JpgHaKq/RkgKfxZhTUoJHM8C5anNl@jQed4XynSHMuc4gLBA@hio181m4sTb0eQjoktK4AQEa8BqDDL38rS1cFnqYEtkBGcVL6MorbBBtwWQEMRiK4wg8DjQVMRn1gUPjlBLUDUHflRF2SNRrLxb80/8lJ39H/adcd04shtUXHdPLK3z@KYwMpG6qgIe1DS2dRIGNP5rktTtEL6xwRvCe174BW1zp3WGyJsg3uqYmImmoNnFZqaOAKFbwSSlyTPJrF/f4DzoOw@yNnbIydbLbMO00Wsd2y9HmfwerZDp4kHzoEGHS9jmN6dnQMhdp2erblmUmGZ7WdmqLbYYrDyqWwniyMjidJYjSSd2MRNOcrVHWbTbykstmM4fq6eDlYrUvL7ZA9o1EJ@79gCsUH8SSAHoxiTuu12R7Hb4eJ51WLaMdW@zR2MBKeUUhkm4EMa4P@D7590GCY58x7jnRyLqrSrXGMrpjoO0OnB1rfxFMljH0F/P4cNiJkjEaES5IZ2KUth04tp1oSayeNuIj62UdHZZ/pMSMexNcXASwQI8ncqzRGyrpLkmuuTI5H89M7@nh8j8L4Ht2ML/XCr@LMu@ZV7vlxSWdicwgQcI5G5nY0MOsgtzrX0FlAJXBGvYpHuDOKHVoB1kFMtyHotgiudoE/koHNA1uA@Oer6H9zAfrRd@9afAbe3Hs0A3kzxIWJMbqswPMnNGMQfD8elyJLkgtY@@Ed04KweO/SHqoQoMaS4LLx0E@omCPodnvBUfQ@4Ft4HhddXeN7WolV5Z5LcHLPkuxUX11ED5sdc2DMzE5MhEyG4Po5PoQOG8mru2UcBR0JPYf39WLQdsUDX2jGkeg8UHkFyxjJs3h8NVvxIFbAPTRSThjur6Yf@l8TzTjEV@Wj1dAPiEYjOBx7ZuHw52g2mvFzpQf8zhYhR3n7w0sS9/jfThCggzjaJjlPNn6T@DyMBVm6Q4sQhFUXs4zHvvoQ8Qya62X4cSS6PadQuKFIVb@UpcU7EpaXuHVTiYe4wudJPoV0N5a8jenuzHMhVuPA5iJs5@OakGuQcQ1Gux0LQ@QuN5aYY1@TCehG43T2ilaluUSgBjFJ0o0t6m6TfhGXsGe8D18ccPocvgiwZ46bnKH8vOGYlrj8hZHP0BiFtBbhAko6QAlRkZNcoBEKJflmCH5xGaTZXplm@1qa7YU0gxqwmGQokNReSFKUAhbPTUUwMLvjFdIZvbDvDJ@bxDY8tmO4OFpxEbWiZSvJomfRMgjkqBkt78ZAKEc70fJDMnjR8hEZTqPlz8Awr1vRd9GyXy0wgAtWMtxHdyHC0d6Olndi8UtpbJyanp@uGi0HZQphtriVKAKkwHyD1ohTbLYjsjl2TWjYSKlMMuQYL4ndJxqHSdIvDf/81hO6PQE9cYxzgwKzBNMWGo1Qi8HTgWbDP517SU0ui9Z892CP1jAFQTCZBPTxwnEIPKjhkeiiMOKIoS/NaMAXEES5WV6OEQu1ZHdER6QOHEqFvJg@UU8lfaATI/86BG7ME6GrbkR8v7wWQfACvBueGHkVntfQ8ZMjjHBONr4ELSTqq@gNmcKyXsRFlH64hGisezEQXn3tB@GlRGBDMh10OJqcw8RGzmiRScgX19Fb4Tg0KMcrJXLvlWgkFUTNXOFNziJnKBjClT9@U3ZC8RC1BRGEnvV0g9eyoF0gWYxec1kX0lR55QMUQjIHarjZPqVrhB4KI4Xj4iZJbcWqZsiPy5MkybUoJiGyiocVTYwxTz3ovO7iEUYf1331Y05xrCWGAEIxg1S4fHU@Qn93uP7uK9Q@Ea4ksEyxXt6UXlevb2xlr2A@mCd7vQDRM8kexpcqR0EKc5JD7yCkmd/Ea9dUfFzywZV8nmgA/Yq275Mt6BPcQrerfQsOC7UE92zR8VQHx1N9NaGuaySDM9VXWlRMScDhGQ8wnWftZlx5xpcVMfrQ@LYx@OgCdhcLOFx4CI8y4F4hOa/l7sSmVS7zug1im7ugSNXKjAtymi4NinnuCOKepm6DaVtwOGgePjx4@vjr0OgWCoW4aKNnc/yw1uJYa9COc8i0IDpoD5Z0W/Qk3gyCk904HE/XzK@d2PI1WcKFNSgDBqTis5@o43Ehy0Ly/ErdhXg8bIiiAtbpvBoYC1IJVR0Dm2xL0HUMBDHHsQ1DAPHVW6B3knprcboDo9nEq8WbTWq@mk1cvNRsilYMi8afEY//LLKWmnguXbfIL3A5lyQ6h4A9PGAvHm0fs@NHu2zv@c5n7OsHz9mL7afHuAX92fMHj/d3GPx2nx7tMmlhoSRedoUdSqDrQ7Nt4p2EeNJblhHkHWc043InthPn7kfGkD1y2iZOU216xvB@n1tU2xzXeKxd6I7OcAzTogvNhtYY11vQbVzQjUXlpkN7/3D9PoOwLejTDrHPO3Q6VteCsBL2fUeW6fnbxdjAghIEeevv/U1yJQkv3qKlQ3RFHq7AOofoBoTHuRsAY/D1V3R7u@XxCGZHZYJwwfPRFDzePXxyxPA0g52Dpw/3j/cPnh6xvYNDsD77@v7TT4Ge@0fHh/sPnqMXBXxy8HB/b39nmxw4AmmV4TEDryfe@EYUVAxOVGmf4sy3OoLiD2yLo96owbNzg3ZBeiw6sVH6WMbAemt2ohVp4qH6gjsvaaqAxda3Dz/9HNp8Zr7BGU5/KpjWH8jPPboAbj3NNik1qCw1qG8VUV2h2VO0OM1HDGcM74MwK3T8QIzMSeYDp0U8Hctk8g6uUcGxb35KAdVlHzQktAawEZS/YKXK6B6XaDS5SSBrkFp74OA5jzw1vohQWDDqfX@pSUUiiom1MggU9yjs2zgepFUCB@B7cNBFsmOXB2CZwIEHYFnugKroPq4dYTkRYjI@mKB4Znnu8Ho42qNpYVYIHB4Y1IstCpx4uVGRGiy4BwvPbBjQbT18lIduETS8tmVRFI/C4002gwGvGCa/Qw1kIp9KpLVtEFIGYdPFqQax7I1fNoq@wA24Tsjojj0Wq8ZVdoyLg0zb4vck9QaGzZdAzZfuEO@xIh6PU60J9SG4X4h2fYwcYkC822wRjyDeQ6EVmneNBzEfXEvREGsk6Y4/fwnabQg8uIbAzwMGACkLPZ02tVS0MRXBOF3ByjHPAY7Ecdv34fDAzp1J2/x/invarTZyJX/TTyFsErqh3bZJIARjEgMm8V0CuRiSyTHEMXbb9IyxPW4DdgJz7u6PfYHd//sI@yr3He6vfYq79SGp1W1DyGbPmZwT3N2SSqVSqSSVqkqxAtJqy/41@PrVkUR2Y/skZadI2EEXffWHsKyko8x2fwhjnMQq3ciCUrB50R@MAu5DO94COnGiaQ5y48QGtX1RxJW1IR2SNfb6PaPSc@Die2o9B6Z8TK3E8Xx2rsVXdD0ncD5Mwmx3h@g0zvGS@ujszMVDpBsf1S@wEKazclR@TkaECa8/rUh2/CHwhr/14tbu9mnmjy8uXvPHYoFv1lRGh/gfGBPrguFB53xksDjEdZccaep6pvDqHEtLGzwpLXGUK2CwD7wIYF/3ul7QaWxuPP0d/WKS3@nj7W2RS2VQMsnLVsMLO5JurqipKl0qcyakCYghOwFZkPW2@uISTC2vX6MvDPZCASjSQzmC@/bE5UdShKjWnV@1QbLIOyhld2v4jtgii4roSl70cTH7I/vZ3i4ubznZyKBEGOS0lYh2FeS84xhmKTRfTYHbfRgcyO/Hg1t/EDueHn4I2u6D0H4It8zy/bB4WjJgPR7sHw@A5cnt/wQW2u7eD5gnyWlomtM1c7oLaW1N@3CNX6b6jsYegMG5FzUoGqhR21WPjqhVVGWbCzgmmGhBVD3eLR8diRTvT6AsyD3cMrSkGETY8@J9ZG0b9EjYeXrRpDfLevGkvsQs2tS/hwbzTOLdIyrkGsSV9NDCIrp8uh2MWerJmYWWEGR9TwJRUS6O3Tclg8KaBHwHe0BANuo0o4HWzGamefIJQtMIXNLN5bWxacNPFtY8d@PNjsOJCci0CWp00LNkdv995PXxhqqHF1gY3Qcb3IKVNMw3sE@oQsUDyOh58R58oFtUl6KRPS@w04p2aPiVi6@wf56hiJF4Ec5rYUOsy8WxRI3XxwtqmUMGiTgNNNDSUyayRTMkKBFPXzbNDnWiSc@OT0GwyMS7/l6bXAHFz@4K@vZ5O5oni3pBbo61BcKmprA8Q@2shF24P9MTtIVeS4qHZFUgbR@sKvP/UxXPErGaFM1nNkYlAuS11dVn34OdbIUqnvlZ2DyHJOXn6HIA@/sIZDgJSb0PnFs5cFV6xAAPkI5N69WASRSEpc6MOSXWdpqMTPwAF9YLATIYzRyvT0zW6ohxArfZ0HlGMqFTlqk2GENYN5RHzRT17x6uDgXyd@ub//H6eLBhJjQdvEOr/Hf9YehHXnlGPBbjE3qyxr/5w2GPsrE/0yVCscmN6UFnO/K2Y4NXbhUm0nmb2ZK29E5is1tX6RqoElIvenhjKmr3Ckn1XiZfMJu6V9kviyWKctiO6SJTw5RjyJ75oPcQAiSDSS@B0wf58D0JN@A/4OAqkEAm8uaziTbOd3EjisCquUZ3zEizUClb88neb4fNRg/DeLipJ6FIuU@hIGlhy4d7zizNeq4QKw/IhYOeDaXcVMZLUVH4hgpdhBQHwb2J340JCz01lKXkA/fcN7L59dzaS4ta13NH7mXt5Zm71CymBEy@jd5leDW8af3W6V9ct0VXDH49HzcnX38XYvW5eAZ1rTzlULP5tWKWonu@gL/r4mWOOFci@IrC5p6mhPD4bj0hFkW0Dy/MC75XjjbNG@ghkeBSsXSpuBBd7EbFy9raWbFXzBUua72zAjr5jZaLo@X8so0fnsIsCjKGT@ZrozOcU02tq9@7FnjlKl2NJ11DBLmGwJd3jWHQ3y8dvIlp43ABgCowaetNCnW@LXUOrdnQ98Tr@Te2VJO5AjnWwgWSNUdeQXn0bid9MqpjWgFgBr3iwmo2HNPfiWPN5byrwahPKSruILKWuA1urTnlxpQjjQJkqQUqOiFdEh@Oozw2Hgzx1wlbUWfyvFzLo@@kY4CoYUkSh6nTVAp9ChFR6ctVO7NCz280LxAJvB74loqJzU26LBhYLfRIi4emHI0hOUzkzvARD0DgZ0CnDVgFrdxDcvuwoPn4nscH/kI6qhH5yZCBvEUrRUxB82/xjfybqPwmEIAJP8drLk@qOOXKCxaS7DtIygWMXhbf@OMxA7pVcqfMYWMRNtdXjICTpTjRCKuVZILvczdITqYV/JMtyOTpbaoZOr/D2YkkdE4t30KkJXUpJW3hTzcqZhvFMqqYymyQYu671EBNF2yP3vkwrCZix@92AWmmxVxEDnwk/15Z/7KuP6xhnWcaeU7PTKVnYukepzNSUS4PJvgo04aZKZX@FuW7E6komztVV1HQ4sWDnm56sCSJ8hYeyht6o349iDJv6a5krtQJm7GEjJHyeUbvc8p8rIxmcJ1e43TJ3yuy5zWWsbyv4/XjryU7yCfjWWlrkuBSrxd0X1nyZlmZgmyWAmoKwcWxv4nteFBKH0wpTmAFh3p@GrZbxQjKcl5JHBozqa3N1ylPLjJe2Uk02ItxamDNGCMGlajOZSLcmBwWoR5KnjdAEExkNKFG7pYqPJGFJwZYzDWvqmUvyKkBDk1LDvEi@kXe4h812OPIqXzp2YlzjPmYG8/ezXECkdCdT80mU1yaoLsIf5SNemAWieqeJCHOFhIHhhZY1@mzD3Yb1eDzWk6YgkJJiim66xRJ6ShDXrHvfV2IiXfWP7NL1psGrLEHXX8sSrjNaJAXlhVzcB/54SjEeE4UlSa8Ggy6eOpIC74bcqGWMUNWVvG4JYJozOyeVUHLHs7v4pN0SIdCnjhEyDdoIBIlhFedDjqToQds/wZFK2pcgpFnlXoTVmjAmHm2wm7mvrgK@dQUdvsdEwnuOR49SOlw0Gj6ngVrtBBWPxY3tR3IGx5Jn45@IxgxDKa0Dcv661XQ/G3nDZ7nvsjnnuUNkl3L4@Cc9@x55GAFRFIJKxjtbzX/3LKMs@Emnw1nEKAr9nGi/wC86V/7vZ5vlWDGoIwhLFpDf3jttzzLOvL1ITDCRVbGk0n0w@5fDZus3IFFVwOYEb2EQ5ePw4DD8BfnZz4ubtJZmWvhoVV02gxdfR20kIDK46Tdx9NhOrDAMAFMDyx06Y@AKEuOiKNEZ88SF1q7XKIiCqiBcU6MswlNhl5/FDShZ0iTZXUBFB@DRJX1WglMoL5mt4HOwd4sBNA9JqKAQkAdJT2EgyUPzX8IByEbps7YG6pnsiD9@jRWYLj7wwCkb0Rg6hUqZuAOHXz8tlIV1cO944@lo7KA5/dHhx8qu@Vdsf2JzrjxoJxC64q3h/sgXfRpOp@aH8KHVKkKJVOUYJUOPonyL@@PytWqODwSlXfv9ysADcAflQ6OK@WqKyoHO/snu3T6DhDEweGx2K@8qxxDtuNDl2pVxayonDjcE@/KRztv4bW0XdmvHH@iGvcqxwdYGZ7ql8T70tFxZedkv3Qk3p8cvT@slgU2zNqtVHf2S5V35V0P6oc6RflD@eBYVN@W9vcTDT38eFA@EmQkYLRyuwxYlrZhC4s1UTt3K0flnWNsUPS0A8QDBPddUX1f3qngQ/mXMjSndPTJlUCr5b@eQCZIFLuld6U30DjL/g5VoF92To7KGAoJKVE92a4eV45PjsvizeHhLtG6Wj76UNkpVwvC2j@sEsFOqmVX4C14VDXAAGpBOjxvn1QrRLfKwTHMGSfv0d7BgU7@CIQBLEtQdJcIjGYQ2Fog0uHRJ4SKdKAOcMXHt2X4foQ0JWqVkApoUbFzbGaDCoGIx2YzxUH5zX7lTflgp4zJhwjmY6VadqDDKlXMUEGDjE/AOlDpCbUa@wnw4kdgVktxrkvdKSp7orT7oYKYy9zAAdWK5BYi285bSXMP4@oaSpSgjzqDxqWpWGlPf7r2MaDktEZmto5GR0zaOdwtw4ws41alooQTmHXWE6GUzDSYaXQivMZC1rT886tOPei1@@hjqoux4uMy7Lh4r4yDl3KcWg9cqyT1K1Qgna7XP5TqsNGt1uuO@5iSMTS@V0KqwR/K5cg24p0CuPNGxc/GBtN9M0aorafyoJMM9fAAAnMy9Z@y6Vvj0ndENtvyZTF03kfASnUU8rHJBR6lgGgkZ0e8TSSqkjQT9B5IdqCCtgLvNeuoJ0XLSMrUD@FP7zZ64cnB@ADSmdVd2SxuYgmN4KuvquFKKCQC/ZERCYI2VemFvv9bx86Z1eGe3@v0@y3bcVQZyjuCfWDHdr5T/NzvJIpnkuUJWTp2lqH8Q7XvpiWMPn@WJBOyX7whtczGP/UR/TgKG475gFpTqoqU1VJpaT/l4miR5AoZ2gLdK6iTcc33rvRL5SPu5nIrzwuJ72/1dx5baC@IgWdhwqtRuTP6eXvGGWCAUSwOIEkgI2Rks0YZZW@iM99AxgvMdBO00PIH5uoLn@Z1IAksZK8aXbNOnI2HwdjEHuTwm6PSu@2TvT0QnYjt8/XVF2sFS4fd@sXl309YD0WHpahjA5jHYZ1GScYo2YGFD40UIyp3xP7EwNksZsSQ7KrT6CPGedB2G3FLJhRk2NwQr9bpoYleykc6pAQF4Ji3FL/OHJmSAexYUx1szWVjTEv8BqyViAekMUt3Qr02xj8IWw9/NcR1gyQDSRajeLnAubC7ILmX2lOmorS5ocA9mMVLKT7mMG6aBqTqIvtZ9K6lN8nbRi@GbMqI45W6nUoCEvNJLISyq@jxyH5PcUakApiih8GXXyS/weMnGeCOwt01wlFpVAUy7umSqKeOlNGy0TUJ@QxvycGgaqqmTYFafkciRWNPqpN1YBBjNBAqeA0K2vjGARd0HJFklWQB@3rREd@YUzF4B8IpSI6V78C5s5ojoRRU/BD5rqJSCIalg5ww1W50HZbK8knHsVDkjJHpp@hB8P9EmsyAvwk7ToAeUcsIAvgoShJUphVsX4kowY06aDBONyJqmp8@RWDuzI650A2Tpzdj9q8BEsjemagPnyjsYdueQQBkclRsmONXm6RdNGDr9DrlyOJ4TtJrXg5sIecKNVVMwc2snbm07HLV2Qq@OMJhXZNR4T4UFa9543ZOox62TImtvHgSphico@J/ZJdIAaIHPHHpBVutJjkrJ0eZkgMy1JIx4bR0xCRYlt7de2q3JIwQmTHZL0@@FKEA9BbiM91OuiukL9g8Nx5xkWZicUxR8DAGOG6TcfKRIevOyRCz6yOcJy1ShuB1IqMbnCC6DJ1C9UXQhP2EDEWwksjqMIoziOLW8YC0NK3eaOxJM4kcqrE/6XHweZ@1WiqHxwE@JIamu7wn3jUmgHL3cc1mFssuVfsu2i5iZayWkOXx6pRmvz@EpWMD2w04usHE8cRHqXTwe@HVUMYvhPksGEqNhFr0QzW4bOLdO00zHPedUAuDEXortDziD2rSpY8WohyeZJxZEzYwr@LRLaV0DMbLeWFvRimbQBMKS0pE3BRr4vaWczFBZchQnygYhHpzQTabVA@eO@jhd9Mf/oZzPy6Bei2/pSOTGiBJF8idVOlRjMfmiJs@6Iek0YCuQA2IpkSeFWnaUBXm6BeSnaRdUyqKjomxS6klP16PZlJlLQUVRYwrawfmW8tAZyKVVmRoUB0sNL@ySqjM2nDd3bsZo2ih8WNrkTrtaZGywYuI4hO1dMQnlpv66RM@SSV/8UmIowe@4Bm3XIIiwrhmxXPVaTlH@KFNwcfAH7ZMnSisZFqNAarfaOvT7xEvKtWhDPvXbIxCfwI7gGY2GGcJRt3@S/@iV9/pdxudoB80YJ@GodvHLPHwcUKP2GGdYf8mpFuBKKFlZGpNomeOL8Nh2PBdn0sWjNBc4cgf2KaZwmg4KV1wmAjSnKMRYHTfJfH3IBkjTZd5vhoVsuL@p2SPl3cK95Z9lp9VmE/0EYAUcFsJCwr2IR2RY5LhfFqYynD@UAYDx3OREQ3nHou9GMYvgUR0DBPDWCEzZZZgNgJ3ZvdiXGuN3RbFIBxioCV/18fra0KbPrsNvEIYpMgrtBTYEPn1nFGUT1HGGIcQHyb3k3vlxZ@MPSDwE@jnn83illmMQCKuraIthbxfkVFGARcyDwxIRpMkBikWdGAW6saA1sdJqPHkyX3UIMsfWBTJMHtTXIkj0oaND15eZ9dB5NQnDk4qi2LRobgduAQpjezc/Qzrf89@lgY/HuKy5gwF046EbBtI30eqJlAJL2lNmNeaKHNM5e@PmJWVx/ZagoDFWSZnxmXBdkqtXMgDJeD5FY@1@kMQxqkE9aSpx2I46g8WH0m9e2XHzMhss2jddJzvGgIzsxVhslxqEWmLE3ycFKwkPgmmiVOMLM2Ah3D7Ss@azZNEHBfrON6K9cl36HAfzSK7KT2p6P5u8djHSfEaLXrVRKOHFOGOQUoL@nutDg2v3y9BJEzeXtVJYtRRZNQn/GiASpBJU@nxFCLuk7gn6NECymG9LaCd2T/3EjVpJKdCnqqkWJBLpCcGbkenTZBLgzYaX2CYOF7haiGlF5xjd0JHefnMOQYZxgQGiKtiPxPpoViDG3VWgo/odoC2XUdroTxKInjaMi0cdNB/TTCKyi@VO9LioT7J5M8KDGmsIcGugnI9BEn5m8NrrT4mKFOkgCE@gxS6RVOy6eLxrfrZtkA@gMClKVla@uZcbIwjlgEb@GMm1ce4Bo6qkiVjIyo@EOokGmAswC6l0/V5u4qrv2DIHI/WDXIYwQaCP9v4syxLYDjvtZymNhYZtyaYxZHk5tHmiMwWF4kYit@R/HIo8lKXNq4AwGeMoXwxDxAwrClhj4cCFHrH5LwYorKPoGAxj8MSPlJU1MjOc0Y6ElVmeL5q5MjNyvHShJGZCQQWFrPzRIjAmmV2lggKTHQzcTFyvJjdnigHLIgV7zPFoStkr8RpqHuOCUjXKuecSKLU8sLNSQ6mxOerTixR8zelvswZqblkKtBHY1jL5JOp67lYaqzalZV40VhJoIdj1hpLBFI4JsJaKvzcP3JNMUOea5tQY5MRW2VI@2y89hp2mbBv834NxSY5Zas1hoJneoar7Vedr1iJBWV/OAC7WKQjA4zd/tOtVZapChN5VwDFpVPOLjZvCGnFmsKpHpuFO10VaU8HKFB72n5bfDje24uFfT2fKEOjS3@4msvlkInPzeD3yrYaVUlBPxvPnW1fdbvZwc1fhh/OsyT7fZ@uBNhQO2gfugQGRej1hx2@GQJxgKyYOyMdWXGvf9Vum1cw4Akldh50G@eU0RAETUCBNnr5cEwKIAIpJ9gv2EBs3xehR99NgxeaEoo6hoLSaBJ8nVKnZ0Ae/NBG@2x9UkXAUDArayaYt5zi1jecQfBmE@osCl/sfIvMk1Nv/W6374qPeK8wRgqYu0sW2NszC@Q4C54wknfvVUjxaF3hXwddw68Ys5i8juDUxKTumVBx4TE2/pHfKY8Hdqr2OQXTCjR5GZu5jPGpXZHqpBwZLP4RYJkPAe1H5b5sDOwm0SmZGaZ6OYKjJ8DoWd6dufeJZXFIJyZp9v3cSNTZ6HoUrAGa7tBaQMWyp@6lltyTXRM3dTrOt5GGOYYhccKYK48rga5mf55YvB6124@TinQNAHfsD0lEvgnl5wQinQHQCJTDD@iJUbT/JQPDei8RUIQXOHhZx7TcwQJ1LGBZT5rF32/sUqkkFgbLy6JU2oaHTEaUtktiFz9sb4tdeN/G96fFldXVAsvcXecbfNxWH@/ENsAgDedy82K4C6@QVkS/MbTWxi5eyBYX3MJCvbi5VQiztdI2uvXD0z/@9d//8W//kS3Jl//Cl216qX3WmTzPyy40vy08vSvge233bHHhvLYwOFvsFJDL/klRw/uVUaYRmY96w3MrzbOA8ZXsSNU@m6LPyKJC3e932Rj@BtJlQ6SbYTYtv4Z8cxTJ2HTTN7776Ed5Dlt4delAcisPSKQB6ATV8dA7TR8N8GC@AUoCLmgHyuX5bEUp7jEcjM6gT1XSMhIPrVmvffRpiSIpoC8uzFiZoBf6PdSAX9Oal5tnWQ34DUZ1yb/Zz@/CznZ/LJZObbGUE0uuWEql6Ce/9hK@OgvZAL1zORtsB1IpF1KiowU0MxRhQAs92j/QXTsJclvWAl3Zg5BUmArKzF5wrt79kbMMX7gWdqw5vD5TsIqEDpmwSPrbQu8OuuUb5LhLxVxtaKFQl7sYqsw4UdH9i0ugRsiGAFHNl0yQjT5UiSd95JGMT1n1Rfa1RbcJEWAk69GbPRr3@AHmooWetHmO7aXwmiMyn@evODcW2Bma0MYUrj9CgA5UeDuZI0/CxfSixVbeRiupmeyFbbZPMh/bOkz8kbJN50J/CIMJ2JrbJNxCT/q1SENuPl4RqUAfrxhVpZK238IyilxedUfBQLorUO04oL7p2u54JGGPEiCGwzH7N6ZHGCkKVKSoRLfwZVkT0epj03kk9KRrOnSw4/HJkUGE7GcbxvZtYmw7WfISUezAPEBIaVO@diPohjLqypCI3WkMz/F2wEabLlQb8bkZ6fPwwtQExv22RtojyGRyHo1naEp6MGx0LhuuSB/0j4eNSQWmLVj5jJqeAy3EEEyIBA4@WfWs5imEuUWyS4giuilkOYSXF3Qn8no07tuU9jnBLlVDQYZdwUEQYyeipH8b66sEHSOu/oFOMFGeEt76NFKKWJK8aGkkIaVMtxkaZlNDx1I1mGNHD5yUxajqkal4QRa6won2kg5@QZJ3MUaArDslvQClK8LaS6wfZ6eO32vEJqdB11KO/tmC4HkRxzNdRcnWSJa6BDUf3XiHWME68nM8CgTPTSqckTVn23OnobzOLW3OIxTkW9viZxsi0BfQ0QVm5BkiTnoBC8vEDBXdgeGJCln@A4R2t9EB/CY3jQmy4mnafjWfdWqfT3tnS/Zp7/b0q0OYSJGsZtmMSMvDbCWx5FiBmTHrxl6VVVqoQg2e9uIZTnuCfVgMEgAiWbv2OXt2mwWETtN4j/xpmgkS6zLEJPtwfVkEn51CMx3HIpu25pwlR3W@/SrvCJhb6Rf7kD84/AtYqE0lqelhnzNsAyjy0/39il1Owuz6Su75Sv457IQ6/jgz9K9wvs2EV@f@GJYSIW5nYeo5/Rrjhhgh7sZhowAfx9BOvtaEfU9C6aQkRagc5lSPpdkKynjME5AfqEzhUtHFxdF5Gnj4iBt@VwDLqbwUC4pNBw3us3H@DPuXWE8jRLmW9A5hjkQrA7YRIRVqBiGry1fu41BHDZdF8nPyxA7GbiUg0L3ZtDFb9Pq9jFysOd5iARfR6DXTXc@t55JjdGqIxkboglxMLc6L/NarF3//z8Pf06P01kr24xB@R@nf02vraX6EB3h7pt6u01vpTcy2dpeeZGEPDI8v/v7fUH7rLwAHUyab8GdrVcFam6S3MkUqcpveWoOH/MoK1Ps/f/sbtGGBd2x4F@tC3RWEWEFRZKfRI96FdFHBVvK2dDESK@SYhTDYwhD25vCChlHjlfUcqenS0qri2peRr5Q9ipziyTBrRKZCrMlQ9hSwMuICRawgwyCVCUVbGLYbymwDmTdCU3x54q2FsAP4Is05dJXadONJiCZDC7wtgg60uUbYz/PDVu5VSpt3bKSUTUlBLSFxaydl7fqzwv8C)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ew8vc)

Bot Engine code:

```
326 
eeeP
```

`r` on line 1 sends the primary bot down:

`````html
<style>a{background:lightblue}</style>
<pre>
<a># 6 "($11k_r</a>v+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[?630=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}3
# 1"7"//[']<a>[</a>']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    &lt;!--     (22)Siii/ \psd
# if-0//   <a> </a>           18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11
#6!@eD>>if <a>3</a>>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x#
# endif/*  <a> </a>v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      
#comment -[<a>v</a>>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  
#[[/]e] x  <a>> >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeeP</a>s
</pre>
`````

`11` before `r` is for Affine Mess. `k` fixes `v` in AlphaBeta. `11` changes Lolwho.Cares `insnBase` to 1, which results in `2` being expanded to `101` instead of `201`.
`121` fixes that. There is no place for `121` in the old path, so Lolwho.Cares path was changed:

`````html
<style>a{background:lightblue}</style>
<pre>
<a># 6 "($11k_rv</a>+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[?630=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"
# 1"7"//['][<a>'</a>]     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    &lt;!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### #
# if-0//    <a> </a>          18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  
#6!@eD>>if 3<a>>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  ,</a> '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### #######
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8<a>:</a>8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>#
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9<a> </a>[@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>><a>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v</a>11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2&lt;ua
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#<a> </a>                              
####################################################################################<a>>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 </a>
</pre>
`````

`k` in Lolwho.Cares code is for Affine Mess. It creates harmless instruction `k1` before comment (`11`) is opened again.

Moved DOBELA's `.^` from Boolfuck to Minimal-2D.

Answer (score 3):

## 328. [DipDup](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/DipDup), 14793 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//     x x x x x 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<]'4o'6o@ ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnM M M M'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'W(WWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461*  prstd!\0k:4op>asequ+40[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4920C05r""Ha在ｕR 8$/
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char* i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD4ueH5EUegbpEUCZAAH@JDpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdut0UiwWSIIkSCLAAUCJLpYrunt1et@2d9fS0He22x7fds55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0JuZBwBBiaRU9jhiY2MhETjPPHny5MmT593W3MHPfx7Dhz2zzWnftD3m6a7Huo5xrjsyezBl9zXDLag5QcBQO05/PNQtz60IMaYw5nqa4zFTs/pjra@zGLiqbGbvGaanO2nm6jpr66Z9Af45xiz9gh1YHaMLkJhnn@mW8VZ3wC/P2EPdfDd857GOPRxqVtdlI8ewPPItMPZMA0tv3DljWtv1HK3jGbYFXkXGnlumNmx3NUbBR47OI20yANU5ozjzPiXGntiOq0MKdkd3XRsdy@CoOYb9eOfpp9fCK1n2qQZIjUx9ci15RWEvDN3pXo@hss9P9vevu@bYZ5Jtsf2bKCl5tjP27APvOvwC2@nrlsZUuSyr1z2LQExPN0vZUnbOC/z2DQdKU/NLrTIrGWs8bOsOEN8vwgvDG8gQ4cTmBGe2ZU6ZPgFggGMPgukeM7C0WCGbxZDwf6x3bKs7Aw9OOsABuPpw5E2ZxCzb5wHwsh3mjrSOLnV10xgant5lpgHY2T0fG5dBgbMzfXphO1DwEmdFQsQd6R2jZ2AUPweugMz2UG@P@8wee6MxoOeyruFqbROCtaesq/e0semlWRv8gHjkfjHQLR8lw@pjPl7MXBCCBVWAY7@uAG0M02SAzhmig0m7bAs9LtAdg7Z1wlLvIqi9GbkAkma6Qe7nE55LBuM9c@y@ow2BUbs60eDzg2fM7dgO2OCHYXktWAWmo3lsa4vF954@jLN6SEbZaQshSWvskjEWCzzZuWaOdZcNtSmkbXlQuZhN5RfEECA4i6/FKyyeyzE1y/J5lofKVmJqIcugSpTBALVWzSnwKzK1xPIK8H0hnsZ0eo7WN0ydQ@nbZg8BbSLHqgWmwjubZzmlFE/zEB1KZ5PlSqy4yTYLbBPeZVZWISGEmmdKuQC/IvwAShmwUOCXy/PUQtZAloJssF3W04aGOeXQRyME32EFhW0CREBVAchqCSCUVYQw/0TheQMg7kA7B5CSaZyhyNBDqYElloFPZmMjQ2IL5SNP0h3opompArGATIUS24RUi5DxPKQMtFRLapD5/oCyT3htZuEHOG5CjktA4ixQK4vk2oQf2EEUqSBzVBAwKsgMVQF3Fcw5hArhiuBXhPIq5gPoapdoCxIW4ipITBQqCtIAokEhsBwURZHloYhzWMSFHAM8AYHNIgO5UlJYKc9KmwzIVc4yIL0CyGD5KyDPFEBCQWBQrAqUqwKIKMAwCgBVcgUmROiq5NAf4uYgLpBAyUOcPJihXJQi/iAeFLwCSSqQpqqWZ@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@4g1TBtwyIOghbFpeauDnC51iqjAeqro2tdHgzVE8QoomBBc6kD0X1dokOAUMXRLRfUJVdmBuqVwPB9uwc8Rm086CoQdZZOh/KOOQ@dJnJHFojSyDfDM5MZrDMaMXAHBQfQ2s@WoJG2XxvsLXiaA5eZnbHjTNlkBAVgDCGU17F7PWDat/poACDYsMs60w7USsglMo3QtUkAdUbXshza1nUIY@mQ7d1nX2d9HagNTXoPMCVOn2VgNKIsECk0izf3lgaUwix0RlMiC4AJY/RsW0b3rq27xCOgDoU1HhNz9T7VCKhevZkMGqL6AswJKoUFLAsCx69VCB8TFBZmBpPyC/9T3YIa0wFmhLoOxYcK7Q7rQech0tKjdqh1OvrI89nDJilmWBGN6HAfNSJylXxgsjsQ1u@DMjeHgQBBhYBzIs2/dkbCFXsKpKhpKGL9HgooBJYe6sCMCxRzeiN5CHF@LXXxFYaZw@CVuASHEdUEVA9JNow9lCAoFI3OAEWgh0KGVBSoZM74ZvbBLZq8M2RSL0wbsVFA2ghyJnRCPJbDkOBn3gQkj0yEVZ9zwKBzDreA1tzhAsh2iKTZjbrKGU0GWXgb0KFt2QugAjFDuBhk3ofKgpjxGKWGZobMSNXFnSsjlNOzzjO2X9B0jka2AzWDC50pSjJeZBHusnlHJxE2EUnoeM@3qNBSxLGd9zzeaRuZ0JGiKoY1FZRRDSQFCDHehQCZZ/MUIwhTrSdYPn4XJPE5M0ETalk66rOaM@VAIHvQKkNCU2Y4DojBc2wbeNMTtCEy8Sk0BVq3i5IVyUH1/nriMnL07rhtTK73UzroKL92hXPNYT3sojiga0AlSsR7bjxZJXeKGfESM/bIy1BU/hYhIAWSocgTPej1QEOwD4LmeGp1EuJcFRPTTBx7vZKYBANG5KoZ@6o28q5j9xrckGmGZ1CvyVZlfWi1JQneEroRJuiRkdFDc0C9gEoIKnq53G1r7B1ID4dJk12KjTolfRU5H6alW90wLZ8QiEs0vzJPwnU6ZJAirRrmAINTzqmRmCPgHSlBEUVwyGT89hMdSMnjfqTOcMexReMLLME1kCS7DPV7aAAShIwBOofRMbyWr6XcuxfoK2u1GjAbKFEgNrvJaM8gGIiRQVJDYJmUED8R2bOPPawbiSTkFwNfcWxAWwJOrdXZpTdwoMaR/UqAQEBWwUJODgjrl/NT42zcvV7QFjpiIBFrHehKRscTqwI0/rw21FZRNT5HVeg5xJGqyLwYn0DfYF5yxQIV/WCO7qLWW/NRiZRwAjHweXUhiXhU323G0LvTjumrBNwElZ1Lozagf@Z39UNBlPZ1gqDS3qipHAhWBw6HPds5eVTz6yL3zLQNqzLnYNodzSTndQwuBnEfHzw42jn6emsBDNNoV647ZIx8qYhN7Xgi9a1xJi@rlfUojBngh63VsDHifBhR8L2ZZE8iqtK0A43LJCDn4dFn10kCmhCSg1IAM/6uqTQ8DChdQltzB9caYdZPpSDJMEoQlkkHLIAZGhB19NcCfJ6N377FwruO1Mh3R8zMscYBBI6ZAyuIJ6PnNQUs8Gr3eItIcUELNSwcQJ2ZoiEDfD5Frfk6MqRKR1jm08P9vaMagR1o7plumhIFybge6FKa05WB581xVxcWhQHxB6YOS8kzxFGfJlwXErjTmSPwrGzZEvgAALs4ss0kcxhkzR0A7rvX80auUifkALIThOt6ZVQf6nwsohE8sInrYE93UStKHrPGKnRa2GKFvvPNVqdQ0Dfz5Wiz1Zml2Y0CHZJSbNiB3uiA15kroYs80yJ9tdpH//jxDcRdUiKhKyAFmLkmkykt1xSw9yIZLO5mdqGHZpu6/IIknsjEZCYTD0ZO5Y5Lfc5I@L2J4SWySf5VkhAWUt/ZOVAfBoH9UT4awKBOA3bBsWVyejhT0XGBRyzbtPs224A4XDsMEgS1aWk2d/q2daOENHTErMZw6gPkL47XaCNoa4y31HGkWNHuKp820Sz3AqS0UswhkYhCBCpD4eXX2rkG5Jrl@/jgG3vQiCiFbDY0Z@kBEkTiELnQ1Im4kgOTICHZx2dhBsNpkBu1PfCQIvMQmGlf0IURd2beCx1JYsqZheEXovRV@wbFX9vTa6wFLpy1wBAh2cHTZ48Pnu492fni1FMLhTl7PlsuAuEgvTboQvKA0w1r6wavmpgtBBeDuuFg9QIpMIYOSjCePnYdENwyBpE5Aku4hk8gJb5qD6y4m7yemQv0lV5bHc5CT7Dy8aB@ROhod03sjDh83g3bc@SfgeeN3EomA7V8MG7L0GnNvO7YptbPUDxoGEwzo2DX5eAQxzXcRTEAGXeq8xh8TAtUhykNHGrm0IbOC83loWhgCQ6eBqtMoz@AvjBO@OlOUg45mHKT6UIPAfrKmTBvJIDJBrT1v0E5iZy1v6KoJc7XSlbNZ8Qg2Fz1h7BrPR26TglorYAUyWtWdnrv9B6bgpRGSNeBxJi84c/5YFtgMlAkabAU@/kBcUha4DApygqi0ZsxDuKClMoUsvlNpVjIQLcMummgs0o41CYNNa8zkDxbAniS3aNxgwgX9tyOZvXkDd8QIAt63yeQ1Vzj5emp1QQF/fQe4YYzaY1ps6E0k1V2M8qGHz5ZBe6dyx7ybuAAvEtGYE36siXyrKvdFGddjWpXl2W84chvc6QRe7IDitRbG@R1V4/WPYyQiXpmNubCZjDw@8yCASETowr4QkploEJBSwusl0G8JFB6UT0EzgG5FYnAZqMZPB98/joiR7DTjXxv2HGXBvpRr8FBUncERKQx5g5KaRfHBz1oHUPORykNhYtCml3ocRw@11w@SAmR/FnLID701UIINBgfDkRb4WwtMAHFou45SA7gKxwtHcxGGbHTD5wGCRJOOPgAGoRFkwZ9kDMQmWdkh2eEp0Qu81k6s@wLC6G1dVaS2obHx/jtsYOzgUY3mjcInlN5GIBGmYvIdZo2bOsdPsrKI1MuoBOosaE@tHEoAbQrEgU6ZUHjU47YF3RxoBqqVVbCWReAL7H7uyDFOjofL5KG2IkCltpjcc/J7EjfyGjSW@DmFboVZn4nOgNOhX4SEIBGIsMpcBol8UdASTuxhxToBY23oOeDQN0VRlNvADkGDhO1mj3Sret9Pt4jTCSrNFEbj4PAN6zEZXxtbS1eidfjaTBtg2kLTdtoSoFpm0wSmTCcjCaKkSYT@jYoBro141eNAPIk2UQemKDm8NYYJbRGpZJrprWG4n9V/CahKIDyEFrCD8CJJ2s1NCaTYv0Cp2pAf4/kfRd557jjGCOfBF8FhYDbfRrkiAjQvUdt3tGr2DddTZFhzYFOo44qZsKJnzayp83Ty9Nu6vQqnsbYyapWg/4hCC8vMZT7jj0egeLWyFckkG3JRq7SrLZr8Wx8I5EoSSYkpCWTn5SSKY3TOhHXgacSp6dxIKlPnUZn4BC8SVpNJkNCAR49A3oZppmIy5clSL@dbCZTcYibjKdBLNficaBLB4ngUqZxRIAz0b4xAVJCxYQmLjqnQAKS5qSwun5DHw2mTjRAOOoGWjaOoM9m86EykBSPSsm3PH5UoZvr6Qd6Lw8Hyi0O3qG@NJpy6S5wTE8zcytLgnb3XOoNbU/LfC5Dp0mONJfxtXhGkqAlJB8OibL9xHCxCmuWbo/d6EjjwgFQTB1cTwZjEJbBsps0cJUxEvTOwGbx9fsAnYXTPNiU4IyVxOe9AgDdjgw/FKKoleBkCWgXtB7FALmIa1X4qIxCSHDRE4zNF4qjN3KYWpXisCwmZPQt29ElIAnEEGj1CK01EurMX5JyQCNfN@YlfF9q0rDjbeggEfdNWyPacnEdmQ8aDSPxoX8OUY70rmCC/OiBeJR5WTh6N7Mh0OSs7QyghYDcoCRWw9Ia@h4Z2x11ZW8CUYUENrhRT967A6XzgnVVVS12Cr1K4IdcAcQeQCFhr9SCLm7gJSngmfQLeY8PCwV99KeHD/f42Ak1tti84jhaa2h3x6BX@v2mI93qp9ke8JNh2UMDyBDEf3tmHtm2x3v5YFk2MsM7zcZwbGo05nN9WGZlvI7dtk0aCloVdRZ@7LiaqfFBqMB35/MnoOs/PzmuyZVIoIx2PlyZNo5DLk6W0/MgOudI06zB9JDLGVNcL4jYbgWr2VDM@B5F9Bj7a9mgjAL3TXQPqhTOofjuJXQf4jo20JX9UQSyho5@wDIFxLVtuCTId7xUslfovrQPFoZTKBxXHGfYXioquZ97vd6cc46czyQUTebMOU/OfI3bXB8xilKBB8IFb3NhooCKFCZc93Y9nC@8wiUGA90MZhCPQDHBWTJo201Un6Bvgpo4X3ymgyI9wskQktA4xcY6oGu6N4YtoE6NJB5aiK1RPYE2LIOai7CeYf4Qd5VqimX7U5Mul542dO1p9GSrziessevk8F5bhg@@r7cAxFa9GixFWhYMU4rHw2AElXCDGJRNmra/kdVwEYZLY@oCRakKbgZ6DRM1K51ONveaGZeI0GPi6enkk6z6BXQ@cNHY@r1MX69ickupRXY@Dt0ZgNhgqck8yaAcxlbPNrsSn/SC8me8u4QF4S81CJetkcAHF8MJVqwZuIjFX1kI4jKy2O0G3GtFV78ZILI8LgQEteGSvTtLn79jDWjBzmV3ZBpek13Jnt0aYOa9sWNdX0jHVUrH0aau4K9UqbGdo08/b2SbHIIw1HAiq8RLaxKswwQ9GPQeXO4KJlxv4xkeNey0sMDA/CoyIDWhOQ9AH2DwBKosTMjPEaL@Tn83y0tPh45nQkfM3ekwzfTkldwzNc/TLc5bfDZxObn5tI@fTI2S3/bnECosSxMtoGga6AcoVtnxycO9oyMZONRNxPdwQqYC1U7rDEDfWJbpgJLRzFfYJ904@wTjJLEXLkCVgs5Ey48PzFsF5obuBKSOoqCvOwlwTOJcSgecafqKInKFyycQrprqeESjEFhCT0KeCFhlIf7PLd5z8vGssDhLESWB3Il7FaCtkZTHlvFGdqHdIDUUgsR535PW2NbWEyS@1pUk8Y9jDHEuGLpMpAVCHhoNtgbSjUKLrPaevWxkpXIztc6azSqf4YeIqNPTml1//afm05NPh5GA9HE@8HtlvWurgIMUaOQWY3H8FOBZwedbQNYZt6c3a6m4rorJEFnpLThwT/E6kgtWqXIUg6VNJEJoJdT8iqb59VKRbD2nTva11eWQnQCBMD84DZnguWRrNaYkkwFmHNALzcGuc4U9s13XaJu0/LVnGnwlWNhYV3zC@JACykSTq2LFILphfYZ6hoUxW/PMVxL7lCB/amigJ4U5I4dEkl0iMYmUKlKRvXuHDiJbVxmxgYhLjjl9r4I@LcjHxzYg@9hfQh3VOUho@MtTUHScCmLQeZuf/0Uf3jHInF/TeaVzMRqP65yGdWbTLFJoamVlpYB6Zhh7eGbejNkz3AG95oKGOPCw6jLs3GG7R68FAWgyxZ@mJwcapvc1bChOLXNEHxqxX5Dy/NKUuWTbem9s9WlOE81MenNLSKlcosC9dttYFhSIgKvNgu@CYCArseapcl5WgtqDAzzQLIL85H2iWdavr2pic3SHRsqDWP73P3@zC/S/WToDaK9wPDM0tEBTwJKSeksLy4@KFnotLlg@7D42DY0IQ6bbQHY0B7KkmaFhMWia2pck0DeGOFHhlzjwJr5AF13BZhxzPs8YfBcnsmiqzgK53VkW9toqL54UTSpBd7FLROA6l6FTJBKyvBD0CZ/YiXTcUeDejlSwFIsRM/NyH4y9MX@DOnxrIRoj/K2qm37IbEFrKzp0SLW2oa8ockc7G3dtaXTWD9Xi4oKws9zTzLIEWok/ydxC4@Ls8ww6Rh@a@@C7LNisfc1c0Oc2rnCtsTuS2tS373IbVYThihQck7@XBTH8rU6hYTnVDJNed@REHzowir/GIoMrWKUI0YxrZDa19hRVocHHc1m4XgEkTq2TSmVzSyasR6Pl8bF/SvHL5cWxJ3KH02PRyEOGr5KV@NgcZdhfN3tLqUJzZQw1U1K7EeNSYb5oucONoOFMKcXRz3Ge6Hxhyc2ojw1SZ2xqzsy0gsVneASTE8vGuf1mw6/LHds0XKzQ5jKpGay5m6WF65TpFVlXYSyiZBc6otiOS6FpsRSwOx6uRV3CVneQaXwNKK60jfCJbC8jVse@wN9SDWIAnWH@XtyovV2I1R3kk2R2TA2a8qUtwtyoI45q3sKrF4ar02sxYc8WIup1zIXu87UgGE@Mjg/extmuYdouO6b3KgL1HaACfy/m6SgtDc2SaJQ9al4hhoLFE7MC1cy@bRZL/YwGr6WlPnZ6KPr9712FXCikFOUWIRVoQLal@N@lov0s45zdVkC0eczBhbMR44pWdpGk8id1lucO@gY4I7g4Z/vZEsWUM3wMcUnCOJdzoU2D79@j9VhG2qD1GE1JowYFDyOUS2DwHK5l/31Sy69OrXs3oXQD7OZtmYgU7pmpQ3tF7xtFytSs8pExlGz27iKqZ471sb6wr3HYfq3jPuQV/Yy7I5X1s7HuTwHgrAPueQlDvfU7h3fCGptqtK0UJhr02vXbtZl5oTYCBXyEvednYHiGhpsx@tZ4NFeqcx0062g1yQajoErb3Tns0Odj5VDpFmVpTkV3dfqt7DTxTh6uPKvls9msr8NEpnLmLKs6U7kw7muDv@cSJpdZyrOwOH3nRIyL0yCyRNc2LhVB6rK@PQUulzOWYeneFN93lKZt2zY/pqRAqHYN1MZAuaQ1vKtK7Ia64@9OYbPRCxfHPNq9ZeMWvLXxu5dAH@w3ryr06FzTnUpTwtnUIc50zVtXj@BEZq5uSwX3g@OwEF/Vay7XJf0BEUUuyZsrax3XUO22bmr8MynmV8Ery7mV8OaFhj8LjLPGfK54NscfuyaURlMgltGFjspAH@pkXaHoa93XYzf4LA00sfG3zHui653MZE/vLAswMkAuWPiem5yOKEuebUEXy8MFhNhVMXGJqu@6TAIH04kLiXww1Po6P@RilaScjVngMh3es5sZF49eVPjSnA5Em40wL2cJqFRn@tQNvgsBPpl2oFzHw9tH3K5V/g4Og96hti9bG3uzibUG9sAa6AO@ID20LascwI8eP5RkFeqAdX@Aa@RGo7m181F6mrZp3oWeKBq5oLTt3kKc9nBXLW4J@yi4U60NHv7n1vE7zeOyAw1La81AH0O75NqePdIlsi0LauJYD38vk6HB7PffdxBpZVcfKBJ8/77wb@1b9jXbG43o0xqZY5deFFWizdC36U09vuaFVlvaTl9@aw/bsu8o@wtiaNJ9sYhpG15ngJvQOWfrfbvdGRi3Id3WNc8yzjLBqA@33qnvipQxmPQQnWXTAPI6Uxn5pRb1P8bPwbJC9weQeLMWGlboK4sG6Wi/tzTSzjouHxBFE6vgmHCkNvJd4RXaTl95Mza8GdDIIqlwhJfPTKBhGe7@soylmhVtvpiJYX@5xlIuJSUdFXJJz4LCoywdX5pbQBepYrkcfy1DKJpLwiiy4OVjyO0vKqIBQiMydAvuc/w1txpqYSNnDcZ996bA5CP2XVDR8LV82IIWSUdGraHN0iz/s4zMqpnB3ZPwbYHONdZXTqsUVs6rUDjFlDTbgE8LPlB046VjaKYxcvmbSb2ls3H@Iinoi1@fMuS0mS7uTPsF09V7fBYETbepiEOb5mlBB5E6OKePg@gozLnixQWXZfdBqEsmmwUOwi5TWxauP1pc/GGbKX3xVO9ruIj7seHhKtAFXEEsu2jd0q2wvzbWXONrY8jZMmbDoyD4TKQTPTMAbQvgPdH6RufRXEGESPoE9peQ8s8c@6PTzbK4GBgurqEKDSsGppDlOBMj17Wg37Ag5PWh@/AUjFkF4vsrF4ZeNLxuj6a4DW1KplUj64ZHo6z@d1nXcdnqspVIXIyHo7HrfxbjQKu0oqPQwzNydy8MAC69AdHKBprpLR6pjgy5ghbmN4oz4zJt/BuGaffZN0pZBkobKGGonC9gnAfQPD/DpUGOtYATKe07znziQIfk8Iy9gbLVc0wyLMNbPZrjebhMKPhiZnjLgVsfMo/xLd//WAjSyWKKPL5d15/teb6lfQfOO7bHTkdHY3iQSbRb4Keq7wbLmnGriI0HsVxEe2krZ2@gObStsSc5Y2tlq1Bc2SpU2KRUjLABS3xt78nzZJQbaBn4bVqoDp2/sWtOZ6alawauMZlhgSK2XI7Ohw76Eg/5uUtHtAb5ljg7eDhUh8T1Q3tRf@fZ1NG9O3eYQPiPhw/1Ds4c3pr2U/uJbdnQGo1AUA6PdH6YwNxaj8URMdpj3C4P9OnemswxgV3SCHFtQxvpbShfc2a6S1vEAT/UPG1JU0Rjg9T/C0238ophtnXnNQ36RczLurTzCD3SJ9S3WM4wvA5KXqfDVWIcj5urI3MzNu7Iti3@JmmbhY/yZLVUgaaAXnefK5dxhf/cuMDC/tl8Vg/P@UIRvctPu1iWV0dv2yZ/r1iWZBl8WYDmGLqbeYyHJ5BbMc8k0L7clTJkc6UMmXWNQJM911yap1/c1ZiBVCYfsQpooDkdG2fCfMOKBTqREw9uEdPhpgG@dqANhJ@AxNI6Y//gxtvQMoftIb2WdhgipXmkt3G7UZuOCfG0yc3C5CND/hkJkUVd4ckCgbjCSl1kiWfQG0ne3mzN9aPmqWqM6EWSeul0Oa3XkSxD77zVcNTMJnrNxqbn/CHPmadkXDJWHalGNIqc0WgL/cKaNL96DRQaU5e8gQN9/oy3ang7OL9lwXzIeKjjJPP8LMxS1dV2B5RZe/F8eihcHV3yzw4EWRKeI8j1Q2lnqeaJ4OH/8MFXM9AIt4r54EwTEF23z@AD8mPH8j934cBntuv1jMkh4I37DpaJE8xWAaLAh9cMNG0sywSUnjU2@ehDP7L0atil7phEB@BKkkni2tMl3TqX6IS5yc0c2Xw3WWYHT1L19K7kH7CAMw3S42BjWRjM/y6YQI3KRlzvqWQ4YSfFvL8CdBFxLwLJAPqW7Ukjl76Zkfvs4PHhiTxylYXt084A92Pc0OPmTmxQS9nIkNRrzYnMd/IVaV3D9TIPjhVp9/GBjAGW0JvPaEjwwZm5uc/ScU//3FItoy3tBaGv7i1WEB@dPHmcmu39ZIndgWMP9WTUe/f4OI17W756vNA7GnsfakfPniyNfrCnKMkF7PvcotnBZdJzQUrLIJ3o0BsFZnzED3y5Vbnq2CO9ezId6Z9D44kS3L1j8sWlmXyqnRt9rIWsvJRQVFFZWS7mk5HF2dDZ1p3wu6w8z4wRSssOfTL8s3Q5CmoOuYyTW6w9rJrxv67FsKy/EuHjIinZm9zqGRLUjP4ATRnN/YcipijKMjofaz0oV1ZYWljzARbND5v2@R2mknW/8yKFTpIHXCUZty4l35SGILoz@MLhed8RjO2ly2BWAQidiwsr/IVuTTVLormsVepFBWLjoraVQb6h32FCKlzhc46nSS@c4wtX1bNEh4zJWxI@cSJRdncfHNwW4cin5epQnz59zp5pLp5usjpgFGP9DhjPNKPXEo5b4dF6S6dTuw6AUlfC648W1@cKO9acrm1NJ7dPwtHmVmza6bDiEBbaKJBuGhNjUVvV4eNazxYvM7otbb6Pw57O6cHRU298QB@@888VJZulM43wq2S59ZaSCSo4S6BJm@JBeVGvk4NQNHRQb5HBIbmwN/pYn@ByFD4avKhTv7B9K65o@zaTy5uTVX6lFX75Fend8ENHlpOzygqAhRV@rCCH3o9t82Jgy7uao7t3LJMIaquyVF6RpXJETr8tZXE4lKYYffNyZR/3MfifhXx7ontOfjSw20b@ltzs9PBES/YED2S/tZLhhjJa/NK3/T0h3L4Yh4vxbRLqifZWv4tsOrtdgOqDMe2ouPvCmDZozrrVN/jxj@yB7e2RbWFmntm49P0WNB4ao4fjURBo5sX3vh2NrehpzG7aP0@Db1nlmwhdOTgyO5GwUqlkcv5Kh@iWSb5ZEM/s4/v8IOy7d2zN384HHuEOR38TIR7tBX0LHbfeCgQC93YmrFpNKZTZNl6sUAHNIUkpohMdoBSk1WDrl/7evEpFucL9iWJFZP7eyfA8VH6mJ8DF0wghT0w6U9i6Bz7rwc4@RqfSs3eMeiOg/iiFLNjkTHSrddXf8ggorV8@O3i2d3yyc/L8uJFtXolJf2Mvx82yILVgy/cnua4IeffJBlKOn/BLW4NNSI5OzMdejBvki0HOrmWtNpe1WabEbYyzfmlZmQztcM1IV4CfJPLUyBdUFnTisIMcU/n4G5QrfGOoSSQV1zlokdKEMquw7KKERxrUznXL979@4Qf5slwOfXnC/qGswIh92@76Kbo6u/0JUtzfOXj8/GiPBQjOmObC6HqDWrnAz@xFTUDSoZx6Bi2WqbG4HyUOZVWrxffjQJi4HGcV2ldM5@UCn0OwgDq4I9mPvcES6wQfKBgPCyXzn7@ZuYrLuO4zCWHjAVJx5lMeA7AT3Cv4Zz/p8vPkgxNCgpttnCE1e3QSg@DvA16yCxgpShVztPx@Gzq/nTb8hgfHz@4MEug6AeDKCzrc69rBT0k6i4VfVuSfyxUkRAwSnEGNA4h4xpbjsnMDd/tyHHp45NU8K@OaAzrmTWY7eHkP8DzT6E4DQH1sefxYGf8QihjwkRwKlDRbJ2T5DQhiJGB8aw1Yua2DRGSuBb0y3auw18BnOEhX4VvOJakevxElAM1vbZIG3tCMBLxxRpabOfUyH371u5l@lYF5kn0Atl/2bT0w/wo3v8xgWd88R2uWfhQJPPvOx5onHtIc6R25p8jiW/tnxMLjvgJJyYwhFM05URqD8xT4WwIBO4OTaHwOBQUsBqXkb@nn6elOM4GH71UyGWQjbNVlWsasT/iaomuH8BULxbySASSl8wAgnZrdx/2SHGAyWQHGF86NUe1VG9hra4uJqOTrtWKVl2Zm3XqZE1@FiK5DWOFigMg1GMSBKLMY4Ff3o0FzklKSGBXlUVyJoyjq2tDOkD@2R2i3fEKILAHE4jTS8RjmCV5Y5TnT4DDJNl4CFblRYd0HJCnQypApKQr@LvSntgcsM7f/nu9CxzV1vE3DU9pcfiEbneGIPCjfrE2zzZPB1Q1@/ZKx3nNQuez15jFatuILBHGMICriIpZtvGSn3qnVzHDeZMCmP/JZNsrMFph/KdNfwrM83zs3T/BLXD9/D4nF7h9bNvZm9iEzLKFm1FxGKSZnWcrnF2bJz5GfDGQHzxV5B8mBaAIx0dGN1/bI3dndO/jq4bPjG6fUUcj49WAgyetbqVNJTjeaoSEezdZ8kTzYzxw/ebAfFMQM6WJEAoP24udEWZWT2SAFgpwter@etUUYXs/dcoxf8J2x1/HNqatQo0g38FCyH5EuLTyV9mn7yPXE1dIiahUKq1CawctEQO/yvX83UE0kL68aza36qRWL3@SEBRXhZUzewEoAplN3Yz2DzH4zc5ix8OLEE7yxyY3Wxdziuiiu5/CwJNx97Nlns2OifIeIRyS/QTIgIgU5EwRdWvsOudY9O8xM5Rc78mOVoofJRBAuZldRPALqJLgjEqXI7ChG/xTCgeYOTKMtBIf48NMIg0PTwoMI@QE8iaTgH@jPE074t0ZOKhOZVpkkkijtCFaarTrYMICXFKBCo772bAwduGf2iB/wTLOJD/XAdGSD@IVODS1L0NlXx0MI16PPkU4juyC5JYgMlIyHqHL9CaSEf67hJIUnR0J6DTzd0M@4POwWEpOkPNAnXaMPsj2RTINE@0RRmiw8@xAzTWcdWnGRymxWCiur4qe4ozNK9o86AHMyQ0BraLJhdfVJIn4RT1aakD66xy9enMeT4iJeooM4/ZMpu9dP5AzR31RWSxLN82tncNzlImlRLt@UEuB2HTA/Siq4XaZclgeuQJeE1VAXP/acx2AENSLRG2ojlhhb/LgtmZE1cZqw0nQ@kVTnJ/ZZLJWiLhJ8yENmFLNHJt5@JzRryhKZGjABurpWFz9vjRFrKLLcBDMlkmTreOvTLmhceHRNUoBeLUSpENgashB0HAAjXklkzuAQB/0FPFHIoUPLFnjTJTg0AGYjTSjXrH6PRS7vmtccxXK54hfovFQsM@C@m@JQzgDYG3Iu0OWBuv7RGEAz6NDKQmwmyG9KvBilG@OIPPLP1AB0YpFTNoOjNhjAmp2B2Rk4@EvsWVBX8HSgyvOT/VYpmRFZeDZH3zG6OEDLD4oOO23@1R5QTTNzQeNV3kf7FKPhoWstfvgHngm2TxVGvCZSY1EyXL8Ld8abirKS6/2IfilAyDw2AP4GplYADk8XDKbKF/gtFvY//znetism1hXlrOWcp@KFbBVeSrXACuyT9VNJWm9ka/fXNeg5eW8mpyLTMvmNh@f6oNc@6GdORZHlWD6T2Yjvbzwz1OLLN5OrnFJ6czZSig35zaQplmrps@aEPXv2xfvW@6Q4OZ@KpwnqTbLdw3eiksfOaqxSZpfbxVzsrIwewfOWf9Rlz/VeuhgXWez0FG/RFTfFTKYRb8I/eb2Chwdq1OW6vN18/z7ZYJrmTabsNIY3U7LD@@hN/SQaaVLV5LFhGBl2OnK7XfjZA9bk1yvH@JNKJSTmO0gN7lYdTnrkNtnR@/3xnjbl7kZsjJ99z4/75BsvXrxAwwt62NujmA@bQwzSqLS0QoypWfXPfrp2lb581tr6s28NM/oafg7x892rJ2g@VgqfrK198uBBPp8G0nDzs288@/rOzk7@YbrwrFHYzkvZta0//ZO1NVXdUjNrTddVmvHG2dkXoprNi/Kf/Tjeevbsa65bz/0f33xfV/C1Ca9ztglyAp4cU8CI7xL8FNSxzthbeM56DP/J/LYbMWtobvfestjbGHC5EpvSX2tWyGtMqW9v/pfvH76JebG6mnnhwNeLvYkVSzFuBAPYcoHtPFaPbWGw4lVsmqnVamDc/C//FuLXvwpw0Ge6Ba96IYBVnMbqUo2ivIvVi2BQVBXS/b@@@c0I83AxUSM1LnjuswY8Yn5TFbeb8GzQsyXgiWhSNkN9b2j3gj@ldE@5x5jlDTzdxo/BP5aOR1NLVeh1HzVSqVRTbknwyC@p764o6ikIADbHWlRDiEq@lbuwqFvIJ74L@L2IEU8BUxFfcbPvQKzGHV5cD/diwVN98Y/9HAmx4tp9/WG9DqIwV89t1FP0rJ1WKpz8GbZZEm37PgiJNIufinH2ij32C6cuZkuqmE6n77eoGJCk0iQ2IyDjNGKxOcrG2MzGok4xFkRjszAfG24Pnz//X//8B3/@ffr7Af3@Ax4eZ3WNXmYD4p1D1anzB75i3REvT8kCGc5WSpVSpnV1mtgASdU8Ykr203fxQi5@HDLlaTIY4YyFT72OL/r3bWSi7zU336ceWijELMrqcAFRY9AE@2vspMZ5vSmh4lSTGkqx0JQ4PwZ5rJdZ4z4Uk6hulsVmXS2oh1B0isgLbrDuMjsGPcgiRNqGZw3@6B@e0LqGo8hr5LYW@FCom89amO6tD8CsKBtqLlP4pLinCrFGI9PUm1CRWT0Acn@tslaqFCtqprUCLqvedNJ1/ZkbO1eUTrvdfttpa/C0tY6meNp9eVMuyerWWJtoU81rj9uTttcZdxRFiL1vrLEjXg2aLBU8p6lbn@ey3PKNZLDxJ0n2JCbE/hGeuqIqbAMEaRZeoD2QETp3@Af5YLFLeJrvNxrvN4BD6qktqp7NuuRjCR@5db@Zkq6uGmCuVv3/rXporNLDTZC55lUqtfWyLkmNl/VGCkC@9EHKHKbcqje3yCNMy0/M995qxvN2vGjfZ5BsaquxVbN36Qcx4ZGaAHdrDtf791MymO4DgPo6KBLJVGpdktZQhjd8WQWBm/VUkCnEAbSbrS1ggKutq/pVY@vqamsL/rfofeV/wfVq68Y/fWbPkjAz/yZr5NQS4FWvnzYy9dPMqc98TbDLmTq6yJlTMNThC@GgMRNiUD31ihDbYBuxEVM2c7ENIfbqw5f/M/5OP3z5@9jSM/gTYpkN7CCUeT8BXsx6YrEn/LHAjL/Aii7o8KSOjhZ/kQvLZF7JrCLxM@@VUjEpozBs2b0WblOV2asnIPlAQDBRLRXFVkqZqiy2JRY3UUT8wo0nHo//k1dqeTPOu9O4s/KV@ySClo8Yoz8I/QuLnn/yC8seIfYOsgryzWU830IMiB2TpLoQq28NcZEdDl1L2Ev4vPaF9HxHwm6t5tFkRId32WoHe7Vyuc5H3defEXdsPNyAtwL/e2uuixeMYjKX@Gq/wb/Hb/HvjYd/Jx38O3qDf@zkLf4defjHnrTx75mLfydv8G@njX8nQ/x78Ab/nnj497yPf0KsxtaVdSVrZjtZpa20wWCwrMOyg@xA6YIi11JYVmfZaXbKskNb6YJJh78smIxsj2X7LGtlLQgIvmDyWNZDUw8@ffjrASAH/gxcxNFWsh0GCZmo7tFNVQgeTO9ap0ID@q3iKx10cVmRs3LRaOL5/g2xqZZLTMaSlFuNV6fxJh4cq5bzrD3V105fsZgLenw1ljk9zfARCabmq3gVwNVVq7X39GGrlUEhd/rEPpz9Hx4Oo9aV/8ND@8mhPbTh//Dw8AnT66n7Kaj@9@/XQBz4n@1Yvbp9WiGhEgiWWGZr@7Sek9BcTIGsUNEt9ZHPDCJ862unQvxF4sWLiyopYdWL8@pFlQyhFQytahjAD8YN4Fj1lTdwqQZa3AU85xfkiC80Xrw4DU3ckHlxcYqdEehlhv@g5Uat/xX@jf93/T95zpIs0WgmE5dXWwl6kviXTF5eXV7573oykfAtiS34QwewY5TLqzoaKdAlmBqJZDN5dcXd4J1IbnGAdUhmq05xZ@Gg@sfCJClZ/kr81/1C0v5zGq8ybbY24PR0ks0mq@3gPGucF9Pe0RRtskq3E623G0rzT39Mp5ZvJylQIV@tKhuMW9S8Wq3mA9tmqVotBZb1RKJ886lnt5UiqFT5fDJZrYJlOwCbBWsItgRgA0sBoOqu1qFKX41dHhzSed4gIwoxPDCfC4VElk79xwtk4mJFvHcv4V9Mu72TvHdPLWffvQtdRiNwUuacWq2u4bRa6J57905siTRVXy6APVt6907JllNKPGk7iad48xAklZAU9olap1TLtgOU2ARvpmTUGR4DzdU8z0m8NUZpEdeiuWKSLgbJZm3nNP6z733rW6fxWk2URHLNKwgAU2GFra1ivl4v5sFcLAGpxPVLfkdOP1VWklfrGZGTg4nr8ZjvpZQ2k1wyxtEf2lG2XYfq7eLDLq9iVO4sX0gmQLYmQUe7iuEfd1bKZe6eZPliopQq@3@1tSSrg8LA/7BPnEvlNzY37jcZ/U0WPiiSq5d6TbmqXeoVHFu8qnb8ix9x@6p@716uDHQtZaunQqv1cOdkp9WqiaKILSK80JGEu4D3TY2ceIPKvFBuNjCHzdN4vFK9T/yhlAoMGMEPJ8WhlWClMhFCMHq4Nx1yLyj@iMOaoNIXX0LZH4cAxxg2yfzXhYd1WZv18WF9ZhgGM5hJDzMZ96d3pxMGsvnj@4ZWiotP6KKHjxB79nhnd@8krW5JLKbu7@ym1ePnD2IKWgszO3nn0H60t/Pw8DlEePZ4b@d479ODz/eePwN3l13MnkDQ@@/ZN2paYL9gL4TXzltN1zV9rOuti/H44g17bRgtA8rPHEMm7L7DXL0FuI@0WT6q8OsYrvb6teaM6GEffvSdDz/6bz78zvc@/M53PvzOD3725Q@@A7@fwO97/Pu9f1Mu4PtnX/7z3/3w278Djv8Bfn8Ev5/@7Mvf@Cb/kf2P4fefIm5/7P8i4fhPAFi//LMvv//jn335Kz@E37/0fz@8@fvVny7@/eDby38Y7/u/uzrM9/4t/H6PwwrCfu@3uRt@b4T/bR7uV3744df/Hf//U/8Pjb/z4df/GF@@5Z/98E//04dv/XtVLf3pv/7w7e9/@Pa3Pnz7ux@@/U/VD7/xr5Vs9PW7H37wB3/1h7/3V3/4P9D/T@j9e3f5//DDf/YX/8tf/G9/8Yf@76fw@3dg@ulf/HuoG3/7Bz/C/@//wd/@0Y/w/3/6V3/7B7/2t7/8P5LhN7nh//6X/4a///pX/@Pf/NZ3/@qn3/ybX/vp3/zmH/zV//4r/@dv/Me//m9//6//@2@h42/@9K/@6Jf/8lvf@ctv/4u//NaXS97fWfn@8g7uX/4juNwdz7vAuUu@Ptbly78XPv8QasxSAT4B7v6lD7/xi8Dgv87Yh@/8BNd6w2/J/09UhcL8hNv@P2BQb@YZfbJggt@vffjO95BE/x2QCP5Den03tMz5cMt3ZxYg628tiPRLP/vyX/yYbDG9UqfhamyuS2optQFdmo1y2W@y/ZFsiPKL89BCAH5K30UJNef3XZRtH370zQ8//qcffvSbH370y9hgSvlyeictKavXUUILKxXuEA4DFu8SDgN@gemnaMxGSn0BNvaF7/nFF18IrXcZ3FRw/x24fkFO/GHcCzcd@F6BH7rjLgT2jkXNvjHrG9d91zBlwgJTTZGisRFoQYUcm6R8hHCWgL7gDoEmG2Sc4Jtc0Xsi4Gv2PzNOBJbCMPzBa5gCIxn8eH4S3CgUIJnUZBKQi9QyxlWhDe5CE2OUbr7MMAeTSWoC/V0wQAop8HqQYrVaLYURaxwfsHLU6iVGqKRSNcg3xuZx0q0Sgpg8ICgQs5Y6Yq2N2oRHTCG8ekCOlIBOR6KiiqlS7SEkWJs8ZAgLgRPYV69q9VJtUkdw7zk9UpPUA8IJgdVSk/p7sNcIJsQTYg/fAyqlWipVL2GCmElePOkWL6QCZY7ynmIpvwzgi2PN2/cZ@0RUSmKLa4dIMB4a36lZ6G2aNdwG/9PUhp8d@g@M9Nsggq9RUn4qjPtvkyK6zXVTDABwJUmWZQY/nIrcZvfBe8JBpShZ@KQ4hBRxBHFA6MBwwCclpKh8U2SB9GO1jY9@EBhmZn19XYjVxZx4KBPpMhnmnFX4NTrveN@rwsRiWURnndayB7hA/Cqlvx7HGYI444DZJyn@u39/g30C2aTvzE1gUipn5@0Yh7KVSokqwK/bKeEl9EAE4FMC9E6QJzWaE0sJ6TRjci2Gfuzw8NBHghxe1oQUsLmaU9COkxjj8TgGMWQ5LafT/lemLznIvkEmX/8rryNxaRiTqWq@Ch2lKkMnFu3VKNADRsf3799DqdCCksoBdE6Zv7ZEzZfIExz4nmrTnAZ7HtR8WeAdc6YU84wl6LpLeJIsKbAE20gKfOkxRyJ4EnG1VIpTOKC@nNgIlhoVFWIHHL6M1RHR4OGdxVIhGXjuHrLdwydP9p6ejJpNJuh0FaneGjl2R3fdBPrtPH3Idx@o5WIy1mgg6JOKigJG2KtkSfwdPDw6OK4wnmm/CBKEWJUmiPxslhUhNhq92Ir5Sy1EvPfGFo/xXZnlLaGWcxA1VhdiHR17FMBL@A@/qvDE7T@wJ9DnT4tiWiliNy5Jg7ZM@Lo9ZngkG9@/DXUKF6PLW1tEAaF@KdHwORqhtIpCve4vUmKKUD/eO4EIJ4dMUbOyUP@CTWRMULoS6mbN1K2@N1jH1T7iaVaM5Gm9kU3jn5rLwVvJF9NKYbO5tmZeSpjmKRXbJS7bugLrpYTZ@Ao8TPiKwL4CTvBAGrgWi/kL4Q4Oq/5qJDz8JMGXJIlKAapZUjiFgubghFH0qY6AvaFXH/kJsbVvfMNj9Tr0paWDfSEG4mLAghU5ktGVBzKVc3fs6OTbZ6xrfG7gjUZy13BHpjaFugPkiF1dXfUA0sE@U@sqWXmMLr6vOuTSBvPVRBNiVqVSe6/kN4W8Wqm8z6mqAA5C7OVLTavXG9nmZX5TzRfyBTVXLBY2VSBaOV8slHJZJVvMFlRVKefz5VJ584oloGQ1TarXcmpO@P@fOz00YbE1qgM5tzIjMGpgzG9lNDC2wVjYyrTBaICxvJUxwDiu55TsVmZcF5iwxc8fY7i9uSZ6@gSPO@RuYt3VzZ6MOxhqIiWgilv@eZ51P14dt4LYWreGe2BxCX8ieSl0a127Q3exCV25bXensutNTVzqb9pOLQ6qVTzwMPB6W9wZWGuwpjyyR9AEqoXNVEPJgiDGn1JKq@mu3DF1zdkuVAoltITTMNuFbOXCsLr2hfzFk8ePPG90pNNugu18udKV8ZARPA5gu1QpFJqNhiimGpRME6925LVcWluDmqFrXQm@PdvyXEktNSFy13BqtXh8O6eoklLJZUvCVZh9AQiHeaoLGDOFeUkj8S79alSxbAuqbCWtpY1Lynel1@tdbVymZhZBu5S4DShyJWnp9mVorUqRcBU2TkvGzBNctB60KJf@HFRFVAslsdqozuybRbHavBLuD/WuoeEegtPs5c1YRRBtHGoMEjplwlXFsW2v0tZ7tqPPAuaUYhCQI3QzQF68CpM7zWKKlzeTK2IgoCGnHHAqP@2tTuvmGiAGmnvQDjaaW8E5cMihqiqpOSmnSEoO/28xqPh/9/Aq/Kv4hlg5VTjBvdBPQShDQ2Kxx7gb0rPZiW3TDYMP9M6SELsDjRYI7jq26/4DwjzQrDPu9dDgB5CFXo80vFrEHRreYEmI56MhbszUnX80CHvDNiBIFZsCPICXY9r2ogCb7PmzJbl8Eh75CcTgZ35C8KODTx@dRL4nezu7j4Qie3D49OG1T8EPVGCP9/ZPQusm9w2iFkIQX997/Pi61f/kD58f9ca2gz9h//B5fvYKnXDPmZCHZz5Q6ExA/BdaSW3BIeo1VtgMDIqAq5bvQdfrnm8sFGfGLBpf8A11hhuuouU7JyvCSbDLTmMogNo66/D9t9gXpJNsfE1R2SwLwohZ9gXbzLKubZoa3tjaWwPHgYa7h3RUl0y6WBiTvrAds3thdPU14QluVCoreC0lIiE8AiDDcYeOjTA8Ac9F6@Jdqjgp0jbHOhvjfcVLHOGDTmh0jP4AGpgLOwggtDWN0TqZj3sgvh59vNUOHk@D3G74mDeDCzFB87RYqXrvnvLMgZpSz1Yqfb2@NwE2Zc@h2mjONF0qiHJH3GdyK9Y3Gm5zBCWVyxeVDdS0QL1dO82eVfL2qK650BKl8tkGaIder1OFBq5QARLXS9A2qdndbMERxUfaX//WT/7uT37tiJXWMyDsNvAVU0QRl0uvKYJMarRaLhVK5ZxaSpfKpXxBKRYKaUVNQw9kswxKaFYpKcVSoaykS/lyDjiwDL6F8qYQ42vRMhsEEr4VAGt18OLELdLE5QGo3HxajL1NaEkW00L7mIk6xBEF7PR4tB9zgxk1aGuYkmW5TQYgNdZhsf393ez@vig@QAsuBNjNimIXLYVSNrv5QBR18tktoQYh2jxOCQ@gET1uyWYf7IrimAPAs1tFcYCWvSKO24iigZbdnf19TKeHFhXjQ7Az7sMtZmDZhGAWWnI5DuBNCA2C7fB08oToHlowSfTZ5z674CeKnwbooM8RD8YBPApyurMjigfcsrODPruU7QJH9DO07NAjig5YoDaIYh8MfQfqoSi2wYh1QhQ7YOpMNXDDWyrxeE/L00RxysmDBBLFCYXWOmei2ArcMZnPfWwKSN0KWRSe6/tkKeOfKKoB0hgsF1pyopgPLXnI26NHn2sDr6v3@TN1@LcDOX30KKcZk/HefvvTT9v9ftuZ7ux9eoReu7uPoLmfjp12v@1HbLfgsSHW7iNVOxtOrz@Q64NWq6KZC70@a7XymnXNqzVt6YghxHoDmPlPHxMatnbBa/dR6762aIqSALZQHAzh28bnwRC@D7Q29woe8qLvpN0Wq8j/qBrTFdZQFek26fRQ6zh2Fe2T2hpj8UQ8PW0Us80qebAhKMHZ6hXdXZ3At4bjDMnLaWNSyzZrk9qmyle39BLi6UQtGGJ6bbitlAuVNW1bUfOpSQU3e9u9OItLyjZLKPc23rLE0@S2mstXxNPtbUlsKM1tVSlVipsvN8aimKzgezu3WYGA2Th00vGVbGw2tzcLkSibmykto1Y2N5PVK6CHB@17G/v/rUTiQtfOkklEF3ujkAV@c/aU8mlUe4lJelLjeLFpsjqpKVV@oh3L3oDVxeNTxx3PdjjEPoCbbGcrdDe3qJRLIqSfySSSSRB4JJvgO1vw9uJrJ2cnJ1@AKISuu99LfsYvfK361k8f7crQcfZteOypvI9dENuRd1FezfnwUzkDpxPQ0@VH0KBCLyVwww04jm3Ke5OOPsJ@TOARHGYn@0eQySeP5uAcD6Drse93ftwqnYxhdXSGp8IaXabV6mDSuixBWDEteUFNeater7VqQ369dj2M9RmjI1NnYA5cjnu4q5qiX@KmFN@jVcteVdu1SWwCcFo1Jimvhnb3lZrqVLt4GOyD2gOMXG3Bt13VazpeMi7GxGpv26oxNrZcrac/0x08I@DgcB0UC9ypkugxPbnOTulK8l3U5q@kusOsGWZPx8ME9NTbyXmniBVJk/hakOVL2jqF0/5X1V6NJV4mq2/A6qyzRFd@kNzOV7uJB6yVBJfsq96rHlNZMV@lWxoTCAkqEdGGrvpO1uqfgS7EAZ9VKoCIX8ZnABNTArBGlzy05Mi4qnZqJktIbMKSRJ58tV9rYOx3@NqSRLEpSY13TaEuSS@EOtTT6jSm1dxxm04QZ9m2omaL1Qm4KZv56gAKVns5qTq10djRqyZY/SEjvkNMqwI5gWoA5u27xIdf/GZySyrUuFuVQL0zQf1oya3apGrhmUTAErVcDTxSjXw2Db1ceG2moZ1Xi2mlmM6l82lpE12hkU8X0uAIPR3QLBJmQmRMTGcnWVlJK7qSTmRfGd1XyfRZAtQXIhlLpj17D284BxcoJORKssJXY8mUumEyKAWbaVsSsSlIiipmDGg@YCMjPUBQR7pmUoxkUmK5jYS5nsAw6yfj0V6jWansTUZfA6@E9Ga7mNrMpt4mk9XEWrIGapBQrwp1lCqU69Ea8Kw/msbc8bABZQwmZVOtNBptzOJmNp3L5iB3Rutdf0usi810dq2oQBFdMdKPGJcYXEeaaTkztxYq4KYOJaeU1aog0wIRSlJJqGU1KeAaRD@mMPLFGlKSJU7FYDdkIh7fVOPxZLyKY91roj@4CbKM5FgchGr8nrItggImVsSyigFmIpE2vGWjOtiVgKMDLF8WYpfC1eXVFnRvM7QkEJRJtkYmSa7fF2IVxkARPPWPVMmsMfaxKw1TW/WX/HuKC5gBrkCnB4IWSiuAdAP7ZOxz3Ny7zeKAmOYMG6qaazbUTWjJQDoGQVVVqeL4fgyXSMt1ILF7Cfhtpeq4L@YzNp1qKSkYcL7HWD@1LlCmY9fn8HZqO/2jnWpg28UhzFNBFMVqXIxdxmPxK/gTYvdpM47KN@OwWGQ7Do5h4xgx0Od9jGQD270Mhp4qeIdNQqtwSdBoJt8/NczLUk7i4wsgmq6uYqBlY4n4exqqn71SC1BGlh1scoA@EY7jQCNVKOD4ayzzauR@Qy3lnhwcWg@dfZ3xLQ6lfEusx1hWkXDLQLXiuxb4smaxXFJF9SwdY/dj1Rg7k@JKhbZBjI7LLzdfll4@eX74/HBfiJ2uvVuzcWSdBVRh762vfg36EvFcPs7YaS02qeWr/pqvel1StlQ8q2iTVUCq95SilH1X59xbJ4@iCj4ffvGH@clWCexqVgG7qhZSar2ubKgsGRt9@PL38ZCKy73Pdx6zuKtN2d/9yY/Vzb/7k39F66jiV1WXxoE3YxASjUpxM3Z5Obq8vIKH@xVizRhHKr@ZBDOfL1Bi9Yyi5izLqrJKRtM2NlN59b5VzfhhlU0lGXOlmD/zsVmIue98LzVbAq9gaoKcxCKWQGzvyCioyv0t5Akl3KDFwr8t3S0DU5SevHrHGFg69W6/b6hkymRY5b3Ett5LW@w9zga8l9bYq1odZ5MV3NYVDJZv4PYVnDGK11OZjTiDTg6rN66qzRSj4XboH77U9Q3r9BpHn67hovl5pw0L/vQNl/4wUuDggjWw6RuvXTGxkcxkul3/SKMtnRXqwAobGcDsNPnhF39DVYt/9ye/@q71rvWFCp3AcrmoqLGfKz//OQRYcbRA0IOjWQU8AwANYc@PLbneHHq1QgzvvO8xHj7oB2LPD/UEo29Bbx5twjnqNlRKLX5eVTcx5h1E0PvSpCnTaTLJqiCEGiVpwk6/kyYYbAOvnoBaKlwKX0EvaEBZDQSn8JUZKHAYQpNpd1quOXZGtI8gQfGUZprdgyiQwlfwKLA12jHtS18JBFZm42ZUjrJLVCM9iA1118WDxaDhEL4CUfxjAvFGbQ0392NIwwJxL2MQwpM8ug1IuwlpmzxCi1wTlHseIM04djySBdqy8BVQAIgKBugFzNiCAFUQMV8BAkAeEj5go8m2WC7JLo1Uqjo7tewKF2jjuWpasLFYwGgIrYsb2YPIVQwHTqCl48VUyBd@CYNKFnEMgHAYfI63Bno@RicbKlq08//OoAAWnbKToKyxe/dmWNVqRjfJKEcI/8wY4ZgVlYO1GFcAFvSRPulWxDTD8@CqgWvIdkDxFKELXCfxg@CqkahMROuVIMD/nZkWOfJaUZFHFTPglxevFR0gGURGsvMy7LCtGlPUzSQLke8A7h1Cis4gCzt@p5NPZPWLwPMKMPx5LDj2HQTRSXQc0Ofb6zvLGTSAYzxzG88X4sLA3xHOTxBCgXbgBbHDWJAVw6TQPcOBTglNPgfHkSVyShKjzY5vIzxo2bWaZ7j6uZDED8XC0Ay@Gh685aezRoeHdGwoUHdkW3RSF50qgivLgSNARvkHHnG0x9YF3tHglw1FjmLk0mFHyPmIMZ08RpdbUlyc/W070HMNaJNmel9mnWGXqWWWIEajg5msEFySIhHCbdBwkcZtUx8CSse6Tjt@3Eom0wf9aNym06meGMBXg30DWhXLzfj3iGYujDMjc4JnTEt2DzcG8b3@MVSpsPrxiWb/JCjTts@YaZzpfHg3MXdSgstAxwc9NQ2Unf2AsBVcwaDm0iwL3mkeCn6b8NnkxlI6EnctMU3e/OaUtUQLS/QdNTKGg3eEnmtWhL70vBP8bq07dYOzVujEELDLocjV/VMWanHcPx0eHyL4p8bU6MASGacNRgnoZAanraAR1G/9nGEHVcA2BoRmJzi3AGsx5PYr1ABQ3YOahQeveU4FT9sATJxuogNVzxfwFvuE5VQBA/KjcPxjawAGFn1tHjr4QVTMh@t1oWBkvkMN5ArUzmEX/HCft89@GD/gbjTToXgz9mZrPjhsdCitGuPVIrAUIhasHcjPlPU18CwChgswWUuIKQCbEpMiBx3Gvx6dc7tAsqTCbkJKM4TgkxqgkKoQXCLMIpcpCODxQHP5GZ7@EW0XFxcynRU4dgxZd/GCARdvRs6M@gZox3bG04cj/yo3A6/w9OHOTBK/VwTvy96e0E3V5XtT/hWEnlvz14Ek4j03jo3jOZ6f3x/SGUN4uI9LDLVv0N0bnYS/LIXzn9pMXwb8V0H@k0rxKwTCGIKZpKfpThqApduds3Tvolv1Pc6pQgJwKEU9cMTzOZ3AMnQDkzHqhSFsj7ZxBPa2eUZToABJ5MOws6R5DoOQ08Dq20fGBCJZ@gXbcRxtmiD/JIZGBk5MSe1hU2j2yQeM0MywS35YpDFpTJtz0SdhdGjUgs4Pc/AAIeFyNVB@cij6T7j/BPwn3H8ySzRItjFpcpUMna4wO8j1eO5cEBLBTIMwV/yUzZkPQQYdmykcBIaczrldwa9To9gBvbkNyrEWMAbwxAgIricyjZenjdOm5eoXG81Upg/MLhIhoMQBdKNJNL3ohmakvnlujmx3zsnC4wahVfLxRqfOwOcGziuYx7CAiDE4vQw8Ia4/9JcOcIXAzzBAQD0MPFE12PESRrIanlRLnsA4DXFGY45Yw0emSdqX7@W7gbrESc8JGwXUjABC9zBLgCb4sKDm8OtkAunwwrEhTBBWohswhnhSUbwZB0peqypc1lSpkCJYSVKAJpAd1dXa9awE/lAUjWtekWxe@eUfRX/to9HvQb1YjD0xLG8wqkK0quCiN1Ah/OpCVGX1WqRcAYPMhmbqDrRce1w/9VtrSGYjE3QzeDqYBfcC78hNRAq/k@TlQzvrREushKwwrdUgi9Mar5a8XgQk5QQPo7l@tGnACH58LkAARnZhNN2PNolGm9RqXHCwyZJoFxEkJ4TkhEfhoSdLkGz60aD3FF6ujsXTBO0UV@WJAE/hzSioQSOR4UW5OJP9Gk9RwwlPP82ZzCEu8HkIVWzks05zYeqNCNIRoXUNADLiDQBdfjNdRbgu8BQptIUyipMykFHc5rMBlxXAYCSCq/yk0UTIZNQHBoVfTFE7AHVXTDUEUaGxXPzL8p@YDhyDn3LTMTsfUpl3zKav/f2jODaRspEKGtE@lGweBTL2ZJ5b/hF9UZ0jhpe4DmzQ6toXNkssULbBPTP2o2bapt3ODDVckYL3Vfl3OI@myaD/gPMg7P7I9jTPzucrvNNkENstSp/3GYy@ZeMx95EThkHX69q6a8U9KNSO3bcMV08zPAjuTPe7Hbp/oLkQ1ZN9o@0Kgj8aybuxCJrzFaq6rRbeoNlqJXA9XbISrs6l5XXInvG4gP1fMEXig3jygR6OEnb7td7xkrfDxMOw/WgnRucscTjyPeOQyA4DGdYB/R98B6DBMNee9RzpWF5Updtegu6/GNhDuw9a39iVBYx9DfzBDDYipI1GhEuaadilrUSORKdakuiktaQf9bOPjso@UxNaMoyvzgOYI0aaOddpjJR1FiTXWpocjxakd/zx@B5H8T1ejS/1wq/jzLvmNe75cUnnEjMIEHCGRu52NDDrILe6N9CZQyV0Rr2KR7gzil1a8dVFTHcg6I4fXO4Bf6RDmwu2EPHPl9F/dQEG0ffuWnwaXit8PAV5M8SFiAm668ANJjQTEPwgmRRiC5ILWfvhHdOCsHgp1D6qEKDGkuCy8ERRqJgj6Ha74Tn3AeBbeB4XWd3ge1p5VeOeC3ByztPsTF1eRA9bXd3Upno34YdMR@AGOT6CDhvJq7tlHAUdCT2b9/US0HYlQ19oxpHoPFBlCcto6fNkcjlb8SBGyD00Uk4YHiynH/rfEM04xFfjo9XQD4jHYzgce27g8OdoOpryQ6tNfqGML0d5@8NLEo8PuJ0gQAf/xJz0LNnkKvF5lAizdIcWIQwrz2cZz5QNIOK5NjfL8ONIdHtOoXAjkWpBKQvzFzAsLnFjVYlHuCLgST6FdDeWvI3p7sxzEVbjwGYibPfjmpAbkHENRqeTiELkLitLzLZuyAR0o3E6a0mr0logUMOYJOk8g7rbpF8kBewZH8AXB5w@hy8C7OteizNUkDcc0/LvjmHkM9RGEa3FdwElHaBEqMhJ7qMRCSUEZgh@eRWm2VmaZudGmp25NMMaMJ9kJJDQmUvSLwUsnlVFYOo9b4l0Ri/sO8NnldiGx7I1B0crLuNGvGKkWfw8XgGBHNfjlb0ECOV4N155SAY3Xjkmw1m88hkYZnUr/i5eCaoFBnDASob76O6LcLR34pXdRPJK8LQz3Q3SleOVsEwhzDa3EkWAFJhv0Bpxis2y/Wx6jg4NGymVaYYc46ax@0TjMGn6ZeGfX6lCVzOgJ45xblBglmLKXKMRaTF4OtBsBEd/L6jJFb813zvcpzVMYRBMJgV9vGgcAg9qeCw@L4w4YuhLMxrwBQRRblYWY8QiLdkd0fFTBw6lQp5Pn6gnkz7QTZB/AwI3Z4nQPTp@/KC85kHwArwbnhh5GZ430AmSI4xwTja5AC0k6qv4ikxhWc/j4pd@tIRorHs@EN7LHQThpURgIzIddDianMPERvZonknIF9fNG9E4NCjHKyVy77VoJBX8mrnEm5z9nKFgiFb@5KrsROIhanMiCD0b2SavZWG7QLIYvWayLqKp8soHKERkDtRwvXNGdxQ99I0UjoubNLUVy5qhIC5PkiTXvJiEyDKegzTWPJ562Hndw9ORPq77GsSc4FhLAgFEYoapcPlqf4T@bnP9PVCoAyJcS2CRYr24Kb2pXq9sZa9hbs6SvVmA6JlmD5MLlaMwhRnJoXcQ0cxX8doNFR@XfHAlnycaQr@m7QdkC/sEt9Dtet@Cw0ItwTmfdzxTwfFMXU6omxqJeS4HSouMKflweMZDTGdZW40rz/iiIkYfGt/WzI8uYGe@gKOFh/AoA841kvNa7owtWuUyq9sgtrkLilSlwrggp@nSsJhnjiDuaeo2nLYFh8PW0cPDp4@/Do3u5uZm0m@jpzP8sNbiWGvYjnPItCA6bA8WdFvUNF47gpPdOBzvDmzHWzu1xBuyhAtrUAY0SCVgP7@OJ31ZFpHn1@ouxONhIxT1YZ3NqoE2J5VQ1dGwyTZ8unpAEN1LbGg@kEC9BXqnqbeWpAs2Wi2897zVouar1cLFS62W34ph0QQz4smfx9YyY9ehuyD57TAXgkDnDrCHh@zFo50TdvJoj@0/3/2Mff3wOXux8/QEt5w/e/7g8cEug9/e0@M9JswtlMSbtLBDCXR9qHd0vPAQD5HLM4K8a4@mXO4kdpPc/Vgbskd2R8dpqi1XG94fcIts6V6dx9qD7ugUxzANui1taHi43oKu@oJuLCo3Xdrrh@v3GYRtQ592iH3eod01egaEFbDvOzJ0N9gexkwDShDkbbDXN82VJLzVi5YO0f17uALrAqJrEB7nbgCMxtdf0dXyhssj6F2Z@YQLn4@m4Mne0ZNjhqcX7B4@fXhwcnD49JjtHx6B9dnXD55@CvQ8OD45OnjwHL0o4JPDhwf7B7s75MARyMoMjxV4PXa9lSjIGJyo0jnDmW95BMUf2uZHvVGDZxca7Xp0WXxsofQxNNN4q3fjVWHsovqCOy1pqoAl1neOPv0c2nymv8EZzmAqmNYfiM9dul1uPcu2KDWoLHWob1W/ukKzJylJmo8YThleNqFX6biBBJnTLABOi3i6hs7EXVyjgmPf/FQCqssBaEhoDWAjqGDBSo3RJTHxeHqLQNYhtY5p4wmSPDW@iNC3YNT7wVKTqkAU89fKIFDco3Bg4XiQUg0dgO/BQfWT9RwegOVCBx6A5bkDqqIHuHaEFfwQY@9wjOKZFbnD6@Fon6aF2Wbo8ECjXmzJx4mXGxWpxsJLtvCMBpOuAuKjPHRFoeZ2DIOiuBQer8kxTV4xdH5BG8hEPpVIa9sgpAjCpodTDf6yN36TKfoCN@A6Ia3n/T/FPe1WGzuSv@mnEDYJ3dBu2yQQgjGJAZN4lkAGQ3JzDHGM3TY919i@bgN2AvfM7o99gd3/@wj7KvMO82ufYrY@JLW6bQiZzDk35wR3t6RSqVQqSaWqUijsouOJYzQO8nsBX8LU6TZ6bAIVme4Q74l1DIdT3JLLB315EXl9DPrEgHhxWhwPXW5Xrgr9x5aDkttTNTakjSRdIKhM0L6HwPYUAv8MGACUie10mjRTkSMqgum3JSvbYR84EvW2v5v5gZ1bV00/VkBabdl/Cb5@dSSR3dg@SdkpEnbQRV/9ISwr6Siz3R/CGCexSte9oBRsXvQHo4D70I63gE6caJqD3DixQW1fFHFlbUiHZI29fs@o9By4@J5az4EpH1MrcTyfnWvxFd39CZwPkzDb3SE6jfP@tW@cnbl4iHTjo/oFFsJ0Vo7Kz8mIMOH1pxXJjt8FXh@4Xtza3T7N/P7FxTsEWSzwtZ3K6BD/A2NiXTA86JyPDBaHuO6SI03d/RRenWNpaYMnpSWOcgUM9oEXAezrXtcLOo3Njae/o19M8jt9vL0tcqkMSiZ5k2t4YUfSzRU1VaVLZc6ENAExZCcgC7LeVl9cgqnl9Wv0hcFeKABFeihHcN@euFlJihDVuvOrNkgWecGl7G4N3xFbZFER3feLPi5mf2Q/29vF5S0nGxmUCIOcthLRroKcdxzDLIXmqylwuw@DA/n9eHDrD2LH08MPQdt9ENoP4ZZZvh8WT0sGrMeD/f0BsDy5/VNgoe3u/YB5kpyGpjldM6e7kNbWtA/X@GWq72jsARice1GDooEatV316IhaBWy2uYBjgokWRNXj3fLRkUjx/gTKgtzDLUNLikGEPS/eR9a2QY@EnacXTXqzrBdP6kvMok39e2gwzyTePaJCrkFcSQ8tLKKbrdvBmKWenFloCUHW9yQQFeXi2H1TMiisScB3sAcEZKNOMxpozWxmmiefIDSNwCXdXF4bmzb8ZGHNczdeGzmcmIBMm6BGBz1LZvffR14fb6h6eIGF0XywwS1YScN8A/uEKlQ8gIyeF@/BB7pFdSka2fMCO61oh4ZfufgK@@cZihiJF@G8FjbEulwcS9R4fbygljlkkIjTQAMtPWUiWzRDghLx9GXT7FAnmvTs@BQEi0y8SPC1yRVQ/OyuoK@2t6N5sqgX5OZYWyBsagrLM9TOStiF@zM9QVvotaR4SFYF0vbBqjL/mqp4lojVpGg@szEqESCvra4@@x7sZCtU8czPwuY5JCk/R5cD2N9HIMNJSOp94NzKgavSIwZ4gHRsWq8GTKIgLHVmzCmxttNkZOIHuLBeCJDB6OV4N2OyVkeME7jNhs4zkgmdsky1wRjCuqE8aqaof/dwdSiQv1vf/I/Xx4MNM6Hp4B1a5b/rD0M/8sozArIYn9CTNf7NHw57lI39mS4Rik1uTA8625G3HRu8cqswkc7bzJa0pXcSm926StdAlZB60cPrWFG7V0iq9zL5gtnUvcp@WSxRVMN2TBeZGqYcQ/bMB72HECAZTHoJnD7Ih@9JuAH/AQdXgQQykTefTbRxvosbUQRWzTW6t0aahUrZmk/2fjtsNnoYxsNNPQlFyn0KBUkLWz7cc2Zp1nOFWHlALhz0bCjlpjJeiorCN1ToIqQ4CO5N/G5MWOipoSwl0b2m00f7KDzY8sesPSPLyUY2v55be2lR63ruyL2svTxzl5rFlIDJt9G7DK@GN61fO/2L67boisFfzsfNydffhFh9Lp7h7ZtPObRsfq2YpWieL@DvuniZI86VCL6iMLmnKSE8vrhPiEUR7cML84IvraNN8wZ6SCS4VCxdKi5EF7tR8bK2dlbsFXOFy1rvrIBOfqPl4mg5v2zjh6cwi4KM4ZP52ugM51RT6@r3rgXe50r37knXEEGuIfDlXWMY9PdLB29i2jhcAKAKTNp6k0Kdr2KdQ2s29D3xev6NLdVkrkCOtXCBZM2RV1AevdtJn4zqmFYAmEGvuLCaDcf0d@JYcznvajDqU4qKM4isJW6DW2tOuTHlSKMAWWqBikZIN9CH4yiPjQdD/HXCVtSZPC/X8ug76RggaliSxGHqNJVCn0JEVPpy1c6s0PMbzQtEAu8evqViYnOTbiIGVgs90uKhKUdjSA4TuTN8xAMQ@BnQaQNWQSv3kNw@LGg@vufxgb@QjmpEfjJkIG/RShFT0PxbfCP/Jiq/CQRgws/xmsuTKk658oKFJPsOknIBo5XFN/54zIBuldwpc9hYhM31FSPgZClONMJqJZng@9wNkpNpBf9kCzJ5eptqhs7vcHYiCZ1Ty7cQaUldSklb@NONitlGsYwqpjIbpJj7LjVQ0wXbo3c@DKuJ2PG7XUCaaTEXkQMfyb9X1r@s6w9rWOeZRp7TM1PpmVi6x@mMVJTLgwk@yrRhZkqlv0X57kQqyuZO1VUUtHjxoKebHixJoryFh/KG3qhfD6LMW7ormSt1wmYsIWOkfJ7R@5wyHyujGVyn1zhd8veK7HmNZSzv63j9@GvJDvLJeFbamiS41OsF3VeWvLZWpiCbpYCaQnBx7G9iOx6U0gdTihNYwaGen4btVjGCspxXEofGTGpr83XKk4uMV3YSDfZinBpYM8aIQSWqc5kINyaHRaiHkucNEAQTGU2okbulCk9k4YkBFnPNq2rZC3JqgEPTkkO8iH6Rt/hHDfY4cipfenbiHGM@5sazd3OcQCR051OzyRSXJuguwh9lox6YRaK6J0mIs4XEgaEF1nX67IPdRjX4vJYTpqBQkmKK7jpFUjrKkFfse18XYuKd9Y/skvWmAWvsQdcfixJuMxrkhWXFHNxHfjgKMZ4TRaUJrwaDLp460oLvhlyoZcyQlVU8bokgGjO7Z1XQsofzu/gkHdKhkCcOEfINGohECeFVp4POZOgB279B0Yoal2DkWaXehBUaMGaerbCbuS@uQj41hd1@x0SCe45HD1I6HDSavmfBGi2E1Y/FTW0H8tZI0qej3whGDIMpbcOy/nwVNH/deYPnuS/yuWd5g2TX8jg45z17HjlYAZFUwgpG@1vNP7cs42y4yWfDGQToin2c6D8Ab/rXfq/nWyWYMShjCIvW0B9e@y3Pso58fQiMcJGV8WQS/bD7V8MmK3dg0dUAZkQv4dDl4zDgMPzF@ZmPi5t0VuZaeGgVnTZDV18HLSSg8jhp9/F0mA4sMEwA0wMLXfojIMqSI@Io0dmzxIXWLpeoiAJqYJwT42xCk6HXHwVN6BnSZFldAMXHIFFlvVYCE6iv2W2gc7A3CwF0j4kooBBQR0kP4WDJQ/MfwkHIhqkz9obqmSxIvz6NFRju/jAA6RsRmHqFihm4Qwcfv61URfVw7/hj6ags4Pn90eGHym55V2x/ojNuPCinULri7eE@SBd9ms6n5ofwIVWqQskUJVilg0@i/Mv7o3K1Kg6PROXd@/0KQAPwR6WD40q56orKwc7@yS6dvgMEcXB4LPYr7yrHkO340KVaVTErKicO98S78tHOW3gtbVf2K8efqMa9yvEBVoan@iXxvnR0XNk52S8difcnR@8Pq2WBDbN2K9Wd/VLlXXnXg/qhTlH@UD44FtW3pf39REMPPx6UjwQZCRit3C4DlqVt2MJiTdTO3cpReecYGxQ97QDxAMF9V1Tfl3cq@FD@pQzNKR19ciXQavnPJ5AJEsVu6V3pDTTOsr9DFeiXnZOjMoZCQkpUT7arx5Xjk@OyeHN4uEu0rpaPPlR2ytWCsPYPq0Swk2rZFXi5HlUNMIBakA7P2yfVCtGtcnAMc8bJe7R3cKCTPwJhAMsSFN0lAqMZBLYWiHR49AmhIh2oA1zx8W0Zvh8hTYlaJaQCWlTsHJvZoEIg4rHZTHFQfrNfeVM@2Clj8iGC@Viplh3osEoVM1TQIOMTsA5UekKtxn4CvPgRmNVSnOtSd4rKnijtfqgg5jI3cEC1IrmFyLbzVtLcw8C6hhIl6KPOoHFpKlba05@ufQwoOa2Rma2j0RGTdg53yzAjy7hVqSjhBGad9UQoJTMNZhqdCK@xkDUt//yqUw967T76mOpirPi4DDsu3iPj4CUcp9YD1yhJ/QoVSKfr9Q@lOmx0q/W64z6mZAyN75WQavCHcjmyjXiHAO68UfGzscF034wRauupPOgkQz08gMCcTP2nbPrWuPQdkc22fFkMnfcRsFIdhXxscoFHKSAaydkRbw@JqiTNBL0Hkh2ooK3Ae8066knRMpIy9UP407uNXnhyMD6AdGZ1VzaLm1hCI/jqq2q4EgqJQH9kRIKgTVV6oe//2rFzZnW45/c6/X7LdhxVhvKOYB/YsZ3vFD/3O4nimWR5QpaOnWXo/lDtu2kJo8@fJcmE7BdvSC2z8U99RD@OwoZjPqDWlKoiZbVUWtpPuThaJLlChrZA9wrqZFzzvSv9UvmIu7ncyvNC4vtb/Z3HFtoLYuBZmPBqVO6Mft6ecQYYYBSLA0gSyAgZ2axRRtmb6Mw3kPECM90ELbT8gbn6wqd5HUgCC9mrRtesE2fjYTA2sQc5/Oao9G77ZG8PRCdi@3x99cVawdJht35x@fcT1kPRYSnq2ADmcVinUZIxSnZg4UMjxQzLrdmfGDibxYwYgl11Gn3EOA/abiNuyYSCDJsb4lU6PTTRS/lIh5SgABzzluLXmSNTMoAda6qDrblsjGmJ34C1EvGANGbpTqjXxvgHYevhr4a4bpBkIMliFC8XOBd2FyT3UnvKVJQ2NxS4B7N4KcXHHMZN04BUXWQ/i9619CZ52@jFkE0ZcbxSt1NJQGI@iYVQdhU9HtnvKc6IVABT9DD48ovkN3j8JAPcUbi7RjgqjapAxj1dEvXUkTJaNromIZ/hrTgYVE3VtClQy@9IpGjsSXWyDgxijAZCBa89QRvfOOCCjiOSrJIsYF8vOuIbcyoG70A4Bcmx8h04d1ZzJJSCih8i31VUCsGwdJATptqNrsNSWT7pOBaKnDEy/RQ9CP4fSJMZ8DdhxwnQI2oZQQAfRUmCyrSC7SsRJbhRBw3G6UZETfPTpwjMndkxF7ph8vRmzP41QALZOxP14ROFPWzbMwiATI6KDXP8apO0iwZsnV6nHFkcz0l6zcuBLeRcoaaKKbiZtTOXll2uOlvBF0c4rGsyKtyHouI1b9zOadTDlimxlRdPwhSDc1T8j@wSKUD0gCcuvWCr1SRn5eQoU3JAhloyJpyWjpgEy9K7e0/tloQRIjMm@@XJlyIUgN5CfKbbSXeD9AWb58YjLtJMLI4pCh7GAMdtMk4@MmTdORlidn2E86RFyhC8PmR0gxNEl6FTqL4ImrCfkKEIVhJZHUZxBlHcOh6QlqbVG409aSaRQzX2Jz0OPu@zVkvl8DjAh8TQdJf3xLvGBFDuPq7ZzGLZpWrfRdtFrIzVErI8XpXS7PeHsHRsYLsBRzeYOJ74KJUOfi@8Gsr4hTCfBUOpkVCLfqgGl028e6dphuO@E2phMEJvhZZH/EFNuvTRQpTDk4wza8IG5lU8uqWUjsF4OS/szShlE2hCYUmJiJtiTdzeci4mqAwZ6hMFg1BvLshmk@rBcwc9/G76w19x7sclUK/lt3RkUgMk6QK5kyo9ivHYHHHTB/2QNBrQFagB0ZTIsyJNG6rCHP1CspO0a0pF0TExdim15Mfr0UyqrKWgoohxZe3AfGsZ6Eyk0ooMDaqDheZXVgmVWRuuu3s3YxQtNH5sLVKnPS1SNngRUXyilo74xHJTP33CJ6nkLz4JcfTAFzzjlktQRBjXrHiuOi3nCD@0KfgY@MOWqROFlUyrMUD1G219@j3iRaU6lGH/mo1R6E9gB9DMBuMswajbf@pf9Oo7/W6jE/SDBuzTMHT7mCUePk7oETusM@zfhHQLECW0jEytSfTM8WU4DBu@63PJghGaKxz5A9s0UxgNJ6ULDhNBmnM0AozutyT@HiRjpOkyz1ejQlbc/5Ts8fJO4d6yz/KzCvOJPgKQAm4rYUHBPqQjckwynE8LUxnOH8pg4HguMqLh3GOxF8P4JZCIjmFiGCtkpswSzEbgzuxejGutsduiGIRDDLTk7/p4fU1o02e3gVcGgxR5hZYCGyK/njOK8inKGOMQ4sPkfnKvvPiDsQcEfgL9/LNZ3DKLEUjEtVW0pZD3KzLKKOBC5oEByWiSxCDFgg7MQt0Y0Po4CTWePLmPGmT5A4siGWZviitxRNqw8cHL6uw6iJz6xMFJZVEsOhS3A5cgpZGdu59h/e/Zz9Lgx0Nc1pyhYNqRkG0D6ftI1QQq4aWsCfNaE2WOqfz9EbOy8theSxCwOMvkzLgc2E6plQt5oAQ8v@KxVn8IwjiVoJ409VgMR/3B4iOpd6/smBmZbRatm47zXUNgZrYiTJZLLSJtcYKPk4KVxCfBNHGKkaUZ8BBuX@lZs3mSiONiHcdbsT75Dh3uo1lkN6UnFd3fLR77OCleo0Wvmmj0kCLcMUhpQX@v1aHh9fsliITJ26s6SYw6ioz6hB8NUAkyaSo9nkLEfRL3BD1aQDmstwW0M/vnXqImjeRUyFOVFAtyifTEwO3otAlyadBG4wsME8crXC2k9IJz7E7oKC@fOccgw5jAAHFV7GciPRRrcKPOSvAR3Q7QtutoLZRHSQRPW6aFgw76rwlGUfmlckdaPNQnmfxZgSGNNSTYVVCuhyApf3N4rdXHBGWKFDDEZ5BCt2hKNl08vlU/2xbIBxC4NCVLS9@ci41xxDJgA3/MpPoY18BRVbJkbETFB0KdRAOMBdildLo@b1dx9RcMmePRukEOI9hA8Gcbf5ZlCQznvZbT1MYi49YEsziS3DzaHJHZ4iIRQ/E7kl8ORV7q0sYVAPiMMZQv5gEChjUl7PFQgELvmJwXQ1T2ERQs5nFYwkeKihrZec5IR6LKDM9XjRy5WTlemjAyM4HAwmJ2nggRWLPMzhJBgYluJi5Gjhez2xPlgAWx4n2mOHSF7JU4DXXPMQHpGuWcE0mUWl64OcnBlPh81Yklav6m1Jc5IzWXTAX6aAxrmXwydT0XS41Vu7ISLxorCfRwzFpjiUAKx0RYS4Wf@0euKWbIc20TamwyYqsMaZ@N11zDLhP2bd5fQrFJTtlqjaHgmZ7havtV5ytWYkHZHw7ALhbpyABjt/90a5VlqsJE3hVAcemUs4vNG0JasaZwqsdm4U5XRdrTAQrUnrbfFh@O9/ZiYV/PJ8rQ6NIfruZyOWTiczP4vbKtRlVS0M/Gc2fbV91udnDzp@GH8yzJft@nKwE21A7ahy6BQRF6/WGHb4ZAHCAr5s5IR1bc61@12@YVDHhCiZ0H3cY5ZTQEQRNQoI1ePhyTAohAygn2CzYQ2/dF6NF30@CFpoSijqGgNJoEX6fU6RmQBz@00T5bn1QRMBTMypoJ5i2nuPUNZxC82YQ6i8IXO98i8@TUW7/b7bviI94jjJEC5u6SBfb2zAI5zoInjOTdexVSPFpX@NdB1/ArxiwmryM4NTGpeyZUXHiMjX/kd8rjgZ2qfU7BtAJNXsZmLmN8alekOilHBot/BFjmQ0D7UbkvGwO7SXRKZoapXo7g6AkwepZ3Z@59Ylkc0olJmn0/NxJ1NroeBWuApju0FlCx7Kl7qSX3ZNfETZ2O822kYY5hSJww5srjSqCr2R8nFq9H7fbjpCJdA8Ad@0MSkW9C@TmBSGcANALl8AN6YhTtf8vAsN5LBBThBQ5e1jEtd7BAHQtY1pNm8bcbu1QqiYXB8rIolbbhIZMRpe2S2MUP29tiF9638f1pcWV1tcAyd9f5Bh@31cc7sQ0wSMO53LwY7sIrpBXRbwyttbGLF7LFBbewUC9ubhXCbK20jW798PT3f//Pv//Hf2VL8uV/8GWbXmqfdSbP87ILzW8LT@8K@F7bPVtcOK8tDM4WOwXksn9Q1PB@ZZRpROaj3vDcSvMsYHwlO1K1z6boM7KoUPf7XTaGv4J02RDpZphNy68h3xxFMjbd9I3vPvpRnsMWXl06kNzKAxJpADpBdTz0TtNHAzyYb4CSgAvagXJ5PltRinsMB6Mz6FOVtIzEQ2vWax99WqJICuiLCzNWJuiFfg814Ne05uXmWVYDfoNRXfJv9vO7sLPdH4ulU1ss5cSSK5ZSKfrJr72Er85CNkDvXM4G24FUyoWU6GgBzQxFGNBCj/YPdNdOgtyWtUBX9iAkFaaCMrMXnKt3f@QswxeuhR1rDq/PFKwioUMmLJL@ttC7g275BjnuUjFXG1oo1OUuhiozTlR0/@ISqBGyIUBU8yUTZKMPVeJJH3kk41NWfZF9bdFtQgQYyXr0Zo/GPX6AuWihJ22eY3spvOaIzOf5K86NBXaGJrQxheuPEKADFd5O5siTcDG9aLGVt9FKaiZ7YZvtk8zHtg4Tf6Rs07nQ78JgArbmNgm30JN@LdKQm49XRCrQxytGVamk7bewjCKXV91RMJDuClQ7DqhvurY7HknYowSI4XDM/o3pEUaKAhUpKtEtfFnWRLT62HQeCT3pmg4d7Hh8cmQQIfvZhrF9mxjbTpa8RBQ7MA8QUtqUr90IuqGMujIkYncaw3O8HbDRpgvVRnxuRvo8vDA1gXG/rZH2CDKZnEfjGZqSHgwbncuGK9IH/eNhY1KBaQtWPqOm50ALMQQTIoGDT1Y9q3kKYW6R7BKiiG4KWQ7h5QXdibwejfs2pX1OsEvVUJBhV3AQxNiJKOnfxvoqQceIq3@gE0yUp4S3Po2UIpYkL1oaSUgp022GhtnU0LFUDebY0QMnZTGqemQqXpCFrnCivaSDX5DkXYwRIOtOSS9A6Yqw9hLrx9mp4/casclp0LWUo3@2IHhexPFMV1GyNZKlLkHNRzfeIVawjvwcjwLBc5MKZ2TN2fbcaSivc0ub8wgF@da2@NmGCPQFdHSBGXmGiJNewMIyMUNFd2B4okKW/wCh3W10AL/JTWOCrHiatl/NZ53a59Pe2ZJ92rs9/eoQJlIkq1k2I9LyMFtJLDlWYGbMurFXZZUWqlCDp714htOeYB8WgwSASNaufc6e3WYBodM03iN/mmaCxLoMMck@XF8WwWen0EzHscimrTlnyVGdb7/KOwLmVvrFPuQPDv8CFmpTSWp62OcM2wCK/HR/u2KXkzC7vpJ7vpJ/Djuhjj/ODP0rnG8z4dW5P4alRIjbWZh6Tr/GuCFGiLtx2CjAxzG0k681Yd@TUDopSREqhznVY2m2gjIe8wTkBypTuFR0cXF0ngYePuKG3xXAciovxYJi00GD@2ycP8P@JdbTCFGuJb1DmCPRyoBtREiFmkHI6vKV@zjUUcNlkfycPLGDsVsJCHRvNm3MFr1@LyMXa463WMBFNHrNdNdz67nkGJ0aorERuiAXU4vzIr/16sXf/vvwt/QovbWS/TiE31H6t/Taepof4QHenqm36/RWehOzrd2lJ1nYA8Pji7/9L5Tf@hPAwZTJJvzZWlWw1ibprUyRitymt9bgIb@yAvX@31//Cm1Y4B0b3sW6UHcFIVZQFNlp9Ih3IV1UsJW8LV2MxAo5ZiEMtjCEvTm8oGHUeGU9R2q6tLSquPZl5CtljyKneDLMGpGpEGsylD0FrIy4QBEryDBIZULRFobthjLbQOaN0BRfnnhrIewAvkhzDl2lNt14EqLJ0AJvi6ADba4R9vP8sJV7ldLmHRspZVNSUEtI3NpJWbv@rPD/)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/fojly)

DipDup code is on line 10: `[328]`.

Polyglot #327 happens to print BitChanger code `<}}<<}<...`, I just added `[328]` after BitChanger.

This is how DipDup sees the polyglot:

```
line  1-10  10   10 10         10-614         615  617
      ...  [328] [] [] [bulk of the polyglot] :!  []^!__
```

Answer (score 3):

## 329. Befunge-109 (cfunge), 14810 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//     x x x x x 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<]'4o'6o@ ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnnnnM //`. :-write(186). end_of_file. `M  @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnM M M M'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'W(WWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461*  prstd!\0k:4op>asequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05r"93"$/""Ha在ｕR 8
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char* i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292)
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD4ueH5EUegbpEUCZAAH@JDpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdut0UiwWSIIkSCLAAUCJLpYrunt1et@2d9fS0He22x7fds55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0JuZBwBBiaRU9jhiY2MhETjPPHny5MmT593W3MHPfx7Dhz2zzWnftD3m6a7Huo5xrjsyezBl9zXDLag5QcBQO05/PNQtz60IMaYw5nqa4zFTs/pjra@zGLiqbGbvGaanO2nm6jpr66Z9Af45xiz9gh1YHaMLkJhnn@mW8VZ3wC/P2EPdfDd857GOPRxqVtdlI8ewPPItMPZMA0tv3DljWtv1HK3jGbYFXkXGnlumNmx3NUbBR47OI20yANU5ozjzPiXGntiOq0MKdkd3XRsdy@CoOYb9eOfpp9fCK1n2qQZIjUx9ci15RWEvDN3pXo@hss9P9vevu@bYZ5Jtsf2bKCl5tjP27APvOvwC2@nrlsZUuSyr1z2LQExPN0vZUnbOC/z2DQdKU/NLrTIrGWs8bOsOEN8vwgvDG8gQ4cTmBGe2ZU6ZPgFggGMPgukeM7C0WCGbxZDwf6x3bKs7Aw9OOsABuPpw5E2ZxCzb5wHwsh3mjrSOLnV10xgant5lpgHY2T0fG5dBgbMzfXphO1DwEmdFQsQd6R2jZ2AUPweugMz2UG@P@8wee6MxoOeyruFqbROCtaesq/e0semlWRv8gHjkfjHQLR8lw@pjPl7MXBCCBVWAY7@uAG0M02SAzhmig0m7bAs9LtAdg7Z1wlLvIqi9GbkAkma6Qe7nE55LBuM9c@y@ow2BUbs60eDzg2fM7dgO2OCHYXktWAWmo3lsa4vF954@jLN6SEbZaQshSWvskjEWCzzZuWaOdZcNtSmkbXlQuZhN5RfEECA4i6/FKyyeyzE1y/J5lofKVmJqIcugSpTBALVWzSnwKzK1xPIK8H0hnsZ0eo7WN0ydQ@nbZg8BbSLHqgWmwjubZzmlFE/zEB1KZ5PlSqy4yTYLbBPeZVZWISGEmmdKuQC/IvwAShmwUOCXy/PUQtZAloJssF3W04aGOeXQRyME32EFhW0CREBVAchqCSCUVYQw/0TheQMg7kA7B5CSaZyhyNBDqYElloFPZmMjQ2IL5SNP0h3opompArGATIUS24RUi5DxPKQMtFRLapD5/oCyT3htZuEHOG5CjktA4ixQK4vk2oQf2EEUqSBzVBAwKsgMVQF3Fcw5hArhiuBXhPIq5gPoapdoCxIW4ipITBQqCtIAokEhsBwURZHloYhzWMSFHAM8AYHNIgO5UlJYKc9KmwzIVc4yIL0CyGD5KyDPFEBCQWBQrAqUqwKIKMAwCgBVcgUmROiq5NAf4uYgLpBAyUOcPJihXJQi/iAeFLwCSSqQpqqWZ@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@4g1TBtwyIOghbFpeauDnC51iqjAeqro2tdHgzVE8QoomBBc6kD0X1dokOAUMXRLRfUJVdmBuqVwPB9uwc8Rm086CoQdZZOh/KOOQ@dJnJHFojSyDfDM5MZrDMaMXAHBQfQ2s@WoJG2XxvsLXiaA5eZnbHjTNlkBAVgDCGU17F7PWDat/poACDYsMs60w7USsglMo3QtUkAdUbXshza1nUIY@mQ7d1nX2d9HagNTXoPMCVOn2VgNKIsECk0izf3lgaUwix0RlMiC4AJY/RsW0b3rq27xCOgDoU1HhNz9T7VCKhevZkMGqL6AswJKoUFLAsCx69VCB8TFBZmBpPyC/9T3YIa0wFmhLoOxYcK7Q7rQech0tKjdqh1OvrI89nDJilmWBGN6HAfNSJylXxgsjsQ1u@DMjeHgQBBhYBzIs2/dkbCFXsKpKhpKGL9HgooBJYe6sCMCxRzeiN5CHF@LXXxFYaZw@CVuASHEdUEVA9JNow9lCAoFI3OAEWgh0KGVBSoZM74ZvbBLZq8M2RSL0wbsVFA2ghyJnRCPJbDkOBn3gQkj0yEVZ9zwKBzDreA1tzhAsh2iKTZjbrKGU0GWXgb0KFt2QugAjFDuBhk3ofKgpjxGKWGZobMSNXFnSsjlNOzzjO2X9B0jka2AzWDC50pSjJeZBHusnlHJxE2EUnoeM@3qNBSxLGd9zzeaRuZ0JGiKoY1FZRRDSQFCDHehQCZZ/MUIwhTrSdYPn4XJPE5M0ETalk66rOaM@VAIHvQKkNCU2Y4DojBc2wbeNMTtCEy8Sk0BVq3i5IVyUH1/nriMnL07rhtTK73UzroKL92hXPNYT3sojiga0AlSsR7bjxZJXeKGfESM/bIy1BU/hYhIAWSocgTPej1QEOwD4LmeGp1EuJcFRPTTBx7vZKYBANG5KoZ@6o28q5j9xrckGmGZ1CvyVZlfWi1JQneEroRJuiRkdFDc0C9gEoIKnq53G1r7B1ID4dJk12KjTolfRU5H6alW90wLZ8QiEs0vzJPwnU6ZJAirRrmAINTzqmRmCPgHSlBEUVwyGT89hMdSMnjfqTOcMexReMLLME1kCS7DPV7aAAShIwBOofRMbyWr6XcuxfoK2u1GjAbKFEgNrvJaM8gGIiRQVJDYJmUED8R2bOPPawbiSTkFwNfcWxAWwJOrdXZpTdwoMaR/UqAQEBWwUJODgjrl/NT42zcvV7QFjpiIBFrHehKRscTqwI0/rw21FZRNT5HVeg5xJGqyLwYn0DfYF5yxQIV/WCO7qLWW/NRiZRwAjHweXUhiXhU323G0LvTjumrBNwElZ1Lozagf@Z39UNBlPZ1gqDS3qipHAhWBw6HPds5eVTz6yL3zLQNqzLnYNodzSTndQwuBnEfHzw42jn6emsBDNNoV647ZIx8qYhN7Xgi9a1xJi@rlfUojBngh63VsDHifBhR8L2ZZE8iqtK0A43LJCDn4dFn10kCmhCSg1IAM/6uqTQ8DChdQltzB9caYdZPpSDJMEoQlkkHLIAZGhB19NcCfJ6N377FwruO1Mh3R8zMscYBBI6ZAyuIJ6PnNQUs8Gr3eItIcUELNSwcQJ2ZoiEDfD5Frfk6MqRKR1jm08P9vaMagR1o7plumhIFybge6FKa05WB581xVxcWhQHxB6YOS8kzxFGfJlwXErjTmSPwrGzZEvgAALs4ss0kcxhkzR0A7rvX80auUifkALIThOt6ZVQf6nwsohE8sInrYE93UStKHrPGKnRa2GKFvvPNVqdQ0Dfz5Wiz1Zml2Y0CHZJSbNiB3uiA15kroYs80yJ9tdpH//jxDcRdUiKhKyAFmLkmkykt1xSw9yIZLO5mdqGHZpu6/IIknsjEZCYTD0ZO5Y5Lfc5I@L2J4SWySf5VkhAWUt/ZOVAfBoH9UT4awKBOA3bBsWVyejhT0XGBRyzbtPs224A4XDsMEgS1aWk2d/q2daOENHTErMZw6gPkL47XaCNoa4y31HGkWNHuKp820Sz3AqS0UswhkYhCBCpD4eXX2rkG5Jrl@/jgG3vQiCiFbDY0Z@kBEkTiELnQ1Im4kgOTICHZx2dhBsNpkBu1PfCQIvMQmGlf0IURd2beCx1JYsqZheEXovRV@wbFX9vTa6wFLpy1wBAh2cHTZ48Pnu492fni1FMLhTl7PlsuAuEgvTboQvKA0w1r6wavmpgtBBeDuuFg9QIpMIYOSjCePnYdENwyBpE5Aku4hk8gJb5qD6y4m7yemQv0lV5bHc5CT7Dy8aB@ROhod03sjDh83g3bc@SfgeeN3EomA7V8MG7L0GnNvO7YptbPUDxoGEwzo2DX5eAQxzXcRTEAGXeq8xh8TAtUhykNHGrm0IbOC83loWhgCQ6eBqtMoz@AvjBO@OlOUg45mHKT6UIPAfrKmTBvJIDJBrT1v0E5iZy1v6KoJc7XSlbNZ8Qg2Fz1h7BrPR26TglorYAUyWtWdnrv9B6bgpRGSNeBxJi84c/5YFtgMlAkabAU@/kBcUha4DApygqi0ZsxDuKClMoUsvlNpVjIQLcMummgs0o41CYNNa8zkDxbAniS3aNxgwgX9tyOZvXkDd8QIAt63yeQ1Vzj5emp1QQF/fQe4YYzaY1ps6E0k1V2M8qGHz5ZBe6dyx7ybuAAvEtGYE36siXyrKvdFGddjWpXl2W84chvc6QRe7IDitRbG@R1V4/WPYyQiXpmNubCZjDw@8yCASETowr4QkploEJBSwusl0G8JFB6UT0EzgG5FYnAZqMZPB98/joiR7DTjXxv2HGXBvpRr8FBUncERKQx5g5KaRfHBz1oHUPORykNhYtCml3ocRw@11w@SAmR/FnLID701UIINBgfDkRb4WwtMAHFou45SA7gKxwtHcxGGbHTD5wGCRJOOPgAGoRFkwZ9kDMQmWdkh2eEp0Qu81k6s@wLC6G1dVaS2obHx/jtsYOzgUY3mjcInlN5GIBGmYvIdZo2bOsdPsrKI1MuoBOosaE@tHEoAbQrEgU6ZUHjU47YF3RxoBqqVVbCWReAL7H7uyDFOjofL5KG2IkCltpjcc/J7EjfyGjSW@DmFboVZn4nOgNOhX4SEIBGIsMpcBol8UdASTuxhxToBY23oOeDQN0VRlNvADkGDhO1mj3Sret9Pt4jTCSrNFEbj4PAN6zEZXxtbS1eidfjaTBtg2kLTdtoSoFpm0wSmTCcjCaKkSYT@jYoBro141eNAPIk2UQemKDm8NYYJbRGpZJrprWG4n9V/CahKIDyEFrCD8CJJ2s1NCaTYv0Cp2pAf4/kfRd557jjGCOfBF8FhYDbfRrkiAjQvUdt3tGr2DddTZFhzYFOo44qZsKJnzayp83Ty9Nu6vQqnsbYyapWg/4hCC8vMZT7jj0egeLWyFckkG3JRq7SrLZr8Wx8I5EoSSYkpCWTn5SSKY3TOhHXgacSp6dxIKlPnUZn4BC8SVpNJkNCAR49A3oZppmIy5clSL@dbCZTcYibjKdBLNficaBLB4ngUqZxRIAz0b4xAVJCxYQmLjqnQAKS5qSwun5DHw2mTjRAOOoGWjaOoM9m86EykBSPSsm3PH5UoZvr6Qd6Lw8Hyi0O3qG@NJpy6S5wTE8zcytLgnb3XOoNbU/LfC5Dp0mONJfxtXhGkqAlJB8OibL9xHCxCmuWbo/d6EjjwgFQTB1cTwZjEJbBsps0cJUxEvTOwGbx9fsAnYXTPNiU4IyVxOe9AgDdjgw/FKKoleBkCWgXtB7FALmIa1X4qIxCSHDRE4zNF4qjN3KYWpXisCwmZPQt29ElIAnEEGj1CK01EurMX5JyQCNfN@YlfF9q0rDjbeggEfdNWyPacnEdmQ8aDSPxoX8OUY70rmCC/OiBeJR5WTh6N7Mh0OSs7QyghYDcoCRWw9Ia@h4Z2x11ZW8CUYUENrhRT967A6XzgnVVVS12Cr1K4IdcAcQeQCFhr9SCLm7gJSngmfQLeY8PCwV99KeHD/f42Ak1tti84jhaa2h3x6BX@v2mI93qp9ke8JNh2UMDyBDEf3tmHtm2x3v5YFk2MsM7zcZwbGo05nN9WGZlvI7dtk0aCloVdRZ@7LiaqfFBqMB35/MnoOs/PzmuyZVIoIx2PlyZNo5DLk6W0/MgOudI06zB9JDLGVNcL4jYbgWr2VDM@B5F9Bj7a9mgjAL3TXQPqhTOofjuJXQf4jo20JX9UQSyho5@wDIFxLVtuCTId7xUslfovrQPFoZTKBxXHGfYXioquZ97vd6cc46czyQUTebMOU/OfI3bXB8xilKBB8IFb3NhooCKFCZc93Y9nC@8wiUGA90MZhCPQDHBWTJo201Un6Bvgpo4X3ymgyI9wskQktA4xcY6oGu6N4YtoE6NJB5aiK1RPYE2LIOai7CeYf4Qd5VqimX7U5Mul542dO1p9GSrziessevk8F5bhg@@r7cAxFa9GixFWhYMU4rHw2AElXCDGJRNmra/kdVwEYZLY@oCRakKbgZ6DRM1K51ONveaGZeI0GPi6enkk6z6BXQ@cNHY@r1MX69ickupRXY@Dt0ZgNhgqck8yaAcxlbPNrsSn/SC8me8u4QF4S81CJetkcAHF8MJVqwZuIjFX1kI4jKy2O0G3GtFV78ZILI8LgQEteGSvTtLn79jDWjBzmV3ZBpek13Jnt0aYOa9sWNdX0jHVUrH0aau4K9UqbGdo08/b2SbHIIw1HAiq8RLaxKswwQ9GPQeXO4KJlxv4xkeNey0sMDA/CoyIDWhOQ9AH2DwBKosTMjPEaL@Tn83y0tPh45nQkfM3ekwzfTkldwzNc/TLc5bfDZxObn5tI@fTI2S3/bnECosSxMtoGga6AcoVtnxycO9oyMZONRNxPdwQqYC1U7rDEDfWJbpgJLRzFfYJ904@wTjJLEXLkCVgs5Ey48PzFsF5obuBKSOoqCvOwlwTOJcSgecafqKInKFyycQrprqeESjEFhCT0KeCFhlIf7PLd5z8vGssDhLESWB3Il7FaCtkZTHlvFGdqHdIDUUgsR535PW2NbWEyS@1pUk8Y9jDHEuGLpMpAVCHhoNtgbSjUKLrPaevWxkpXIztc6azSqf4YeIqNPTml1//afm05NPh5GA9HE@8HtlvWurgIMUaOQWY3H8FOBZwedbQNYZt6c3a6m4rorJEFnpLThwT/E6kgtWqXIUg6VNJEJoJdT8iqb59VKRbD2nTva11eWQnQCBMD84DZnguWRrNaYkkwFmHNALzcGuc4U9s13XaJu0/LVnGnwlWNhYV3zC@JACykSTq2LFILphfYZ6hoUxW/PMVxL7lCB/amigJ4U5I4dEkl0iMYmUKlKRvXuHDiJbVxmxgYhLjjl9r4I@LcjHxzYg@9hfQh3VOUho@MtTUHScCmLQeZuf/0Uf3jHInF/TeaVzMRqP65yGdWbTLFJoamVlpYB6Zhh7eGbejNkz3AG95oKGOPCw6jLs3GG7R68FAWgyxZ@mJwcapvc1bChOLXNEHxqxX5Dy/NKUuWTbem9s9WlOE81MenNLSKlcosC9dttYFhSIgKvNgu@CYCArseapcl5WgtqDAzzQLIL85H2iWdavr2pic3SHRsqDWP73P3@zC/S/WToDaK9wPDM0tEBTwJKSeksLy4@KFnotLlg@7D42DY0IQ6bbQHY0B7KkmaFhMWia2pck0DeGOFHhlzjwJr5AF13BZhxzPs8YfBcnsmiqzgK53VkW9toqL54UTSpBd7FLROA6l6FTJBKyvBD0CZ/YiXTcUeDejlSwFIsRM/NyH4y9MX@DOnxrIRoj/K2qm37IbEFrKzp0SLW2oa8ockc7G3dtaXTWD9Xi4oKws9zTzLIEWok/ydxC4@Ls8ww6Rh@a@@C7LNisfc1c0Oc2rnCtsTuS2tS373IbVYThihQck7@XBTH8rU6hYTnVDJNed@REHzowir/GIoMrWKUI0YxrZDa19hRVocHHc1m4XgEkTq2TSmVzSyasR6Pl8bF/SvHL5cWxJ3KH02PRyEOGr5KV@NgcZdhfN3tLqUJzZQw1U1K7EeNSYb5oucONoOFMKcXRz3Ge6Hxhyc2ojw1SZ2xqzsy0gsVneASTE8vGuf1mw6/LHds0XKzQ5jKpGay5m6WF65TpFVlXYSyiZBc6otiOS6FpsRSwOx6uRV3CVneQaXwNKK60jfCJbC8jVse@wN9SDWIAnWH@XtyovV2I1R3kk2R2TA2a8qUtwtyoI45q3sKrF4ar02sxYc8WIup1zIXu87UgGE@Mjg/extmuYdouO6b3KgL1HaACfy/m6SgtDc2SaJQ9al4hhoLFE7MC1cy@bRZL/YwGr6WlPnZ6KPr9712FXCikFOUWIRVoQLal@N@lov0s45zdVkC0eczBhbMR44pWdpGk8id1lucO@gY4I7g4Z/vZEsWUM3wMcUnCOJdzoU2D79@j9VhG2qD1GE1JowYFDyOUS2DwHK5l/31Sy69OrXs3oXQD7OZtmYgU7pmpQ3tF7xtFytSs8pExlGz27iKqZ471sb6wr3HYfq3jPuQV/Yy7I5X1s7HuTwHgrAPueQlDvfU7h3fCGptqtK0UJhr02vXbtZl5oTYCBXyEvednYHiGhpsx@tZ4NFeqcx0062g1yQajoErb3Tns0Odj5VDpFmVpTkV3dfqt7DTxTh6uPKvls9msr8NEpnLmLKs6U7kw7muDv@cSJpdZyrOwOH3nRIyL0yCyRNc2LhVB6rK@PQUulzOWYeneFN93lKZt2zY/pqRAqHYN1MZAuaQ1vKtK7Ia64@9OYbPRCxfHPNq9ZeMWvLXxu5dAH@w3ryr06FzTnUpTwtnUIc50zVtXj@BEZq5uSwX3g@OwEF/Vay7XJf0BEUUuyZsrax3XUO22bmr8MynmV8Ery7mV8OaFhj8LjLPGfK54NscfuyaURlMgltGFjspAH@pkXaHoa93XYzf4LA00sfG3zHui653MZE/vLAswMkAuWPiem5yOKEuebUEXy8MFhNhVMXGJqu@6TAIH04kLiXww1Po6P@RilaScjVngMh3es5sZF49eVPjSnA5Em40wL2cJqFRn@tQNvgsBPpl2oFzHw9tH3K5V/g4Og96hti9bG3uzibUG9sAa6AO@ID20LascwI8eP5RkFeqAdX@Aa@RGo7m181F6mrZp3oWeKBq5oLTt3kKc9nBXLW4J@yi4U60NHv7n1vE7zeOyAw1La81AH0O75NqePdIlsi0LauJYD38vk6HB7PffdxBpZVcfKBJ8/77wb@1b9jXbG43o0xqZY5deFFWizdC36U09vuaFVlvaTl9@aw/bsu8o@wtiaNJ9sYhpG15ngJvQOWfrfbvdGRi3Id3WNc8yzjLBqA@33qnvipQxmPQQnWXTAPI6Uxn5pRb1P8bPwbJC9weQeLMWGlboK4sG6Wi/tzTSzjouHxBFE6vgmHCkNvJd4RXaTl95Mza8GdDIIqlwhJfPTKBhGe7@soylmhVtvpiJYX@5xlIuJSUdFXJJz4LCoywdX5pbQBepYrkcfy1DKJpLwiiy4OVjyO0vKqIBQiMydAvuc/w1txpqYSNnDcZ996bA5CP2XVDR8LV82IIWSUdGraHN0iz/s4zMqpnB3ZPwbYHONdZXTqsUVs6rUDjFlDTbgE8LPlB046VjaKYxcvmbSb2ls3H@Iinoi1@fMuS0mS7uTPsF09V7fBYETbepiEOb5mlBB5E6OKePg@gozLnixQWXZfdBqEsmmwUOwi5TWxauP1pc/GGbKX3xVO9ruIj7seHhKtAFXEEsu2jd0q2wvzbWXONrY8jZMmbDoyD4TKQTPTMAbQvgPdH6RufRXEGESPoE9peQ8s8c@6PTzbK4GBgurqEKDSsGppDlOBMj17Wg37Ag5PWh@/AUjFkF4vsrF4ZeNLxuj6a4DW1KplUj64ZHo6z@d1nXcdnqspVIXIyHo7HrfxbjQKu0oqPQwzNydy8MAC69AdHKBprpLR6pjgy5ghbmN4oz4zJt/BuGaffZN0pZBkobKGGonC9gnAfQPD/DpUGOtYATKe07znziQIfk8Iy9gbLVc0wyLMNbPZrjebhMKPhiZnjLgVsfMo/xLd//WAjSyWKKPL5d15/teb6lfQfOO7bHTkdHY3iQSbRb4Keq7wbLmnGriI0HsVxEe2krZ2@gObStsSc5Y2tlq1Bc2SpU2KRUjLABS3xt78nzZJQbaBn4bVqoDp2/sWtOZ6alawauMZlhgSK2XI7Ohw76Eg/5uUtHtAb5ljg7eDhUh8T1Q3tRf@fZ1NG9O3eYQPiPhw/1Ds4c3pr2U/uJbdnQGo1AUA6PdH6YwNxaj8URMdpj3C4P9OnemswxgV3SCHFtQxvpbShfc2a6S1vEAT/UPG1JU0Rjg9T/C0238ophtnXnNQ36RczLurTzCD3SJ9S3WM4wvA5KXqfDVWIcj5urI3MzNu7Iti3@JmmbhY/yZLVUgaaAXnefK5dxhf/cuMDC/tl8Vg/P@UIRvctPu1iWV0dv2yZ/r1iWZBl8WYDmGLqbeYyHJ5BbMc8k0L7clTJkc6UMmXWNQJM911yap1/c1ZiBVCYfsQpooDkdG2fCfMOKBTqREw9uEdPhpgG@dqANhJ@AxNI6Y//gxtvQMoftIb2WdhgipXmkt3G7UZuOCfG0yc3C5CND/hkJkUVd4ckCgbjCSl1kiWfQG0ne3mzN9aPmqWqM6EWSeul0Oa3XkSxD77zVcNTMJnrNxqbn/CHPmadkXDJWHalGNIqc0WgL/cKaNL96DRQaU5e8gQN9/oy3ang7OL9lwXzIeKjjJPP8LMxS1dV2B5RZe/F8eihcHV3yzw4EWRKeI8j1Q2lnqeaJ4OH/8MFXM9AIt4r54EwTEF23z@AD8mPH8j934cBntuv1jMkh4I37DpaJE8xWAaLAh9cMNG0sywSUnjU2@ehDP7L0atil7phEB@BKkkni2tMl3TqX6IS5yc0c2Xw3WWYHT1L19K7kH7CAMw3S42BjWRjM/y6YQI3KRlzvqWQ4YSfFvL8CdBFxLwLJAPqW7Ukjl76Zkfvs4PHhiTxylYXt084A92Pc0OPmTmxQS9nIkNRrzYnMd/IVaV3D9TIPjhVp9/GBjAGW0JvPaEjwwZm5uc/ScU//3FItoy3tBaGv7i1WEB@dPHmcmu39ZIndgWMP9WTUe/f4OI17W756vNA7GnsfakfPniyNfrCnKMkF7PvcotnBZdJzQUrLIJ3o0BsFZnzED3y5Vbnq2CO9ezId6Z9D44kS3L1j8sWlmXyqnRt9rIWsvJRQVFFZWS7mk5HF2dDZ1p3wu6w8z4wRSssOfTL8s3Q5CmoOuYyTW6w9rJrxv67FsKy/EuHjIinZm9zqGRLUjP4ATRnN/YcipijKMjofaz0oV1ZYWljzARbND5v2@R2mknW/8yKFTpIHXCUZty4l35SGILoz@MLhed8RjO2ly2BWAQidiwsr/IVuTTVLormsVepFBWLjoraVQb6h32FCKlzhc46nSS@c4wtX1bNEh4zJWxI@cSJRdncfHNwW4cin5epQnz59zp5pLp5usjpgFGP9DhjPNKPXEo5b4dF6S6dTuw6AUlfC648W1@cKO9acrm1NJ7dPwtHmVmza6bDiEBbaKJBuGhNjUVvV4eNazxYvM7otbb6Pw57O6cHRU298QB@@888VJZulM43wq2S59ZaSCSo4S6BJm@JBeVGvk4NQNHRQb5HBIbmwN/pYn@ByFD4avKhTv7B9K65o@zaTy5uTVX6lFX75Fend8ENHlpOzygqAhRV@rCCH3o9t82Jgy7uao7t3LJMIaquyVF6RpXJETr8tZXE4lKYYffNyZR/3MfifhXx7ontOfjSw20b@ltzs9PBES/YED2S/tZLhhjJa/NK3/T0h3L4Yh4vxbRLqifZWv4tsOrtdgOqDMe2ouPvCmDZozrrVN/jxj@yB7e2RbWFmntm49P0WNB4ao4fjURBooYjFqweutwqzgHyT3NHYih7b7Kb9gzf43la@29CVg7O1EwkrlUom5@9@iO6t5LsK8XA/viEQwr57x9b8fX/gEW6F9Hcb4hlg0AnRcY@uQCBwE2jCqtWUQplt4w0MFVAxkpQiOtFJS0FaDbZ@6W/iq1SUK9zIKFZE5m@yDA9O5Yd/Alw8thDyxKQzha174LMebAFkdHw9e8eo2wJ6klLIgk3ORPdkV/29kYDS@uWzg2d7xyc7J8@PG9nmlZj0dwBz3CwLUgv2hn@S64qQd59sIA75UcC0h9iE5OhofezuuEG@GOTsWtZqc1mbZUrcxjjrl5aVydBW2Ix0BfhJIk@NfEG3QScOO8gxlY@/k7nCd5CaRFJxnYMWKU0oswrLLkp4pEE1Xrd8/@s3g5Avy@XQlyfsn94KjNi37a6foquz258gxf2dg8fPj/ZYgOCMaS6MrjeolQv8cF9UGSQdyqln0KqaGov7UeJQVrVafD8OhInLcVahDch0sC7wOQQLqINbl/3YGyyxTvCBgvGwUDL/@ZuZq7iMC0STEDYeIBVnPuUxADvBTYV/9pMuP3g@OEokuALHGVL7SEc2CP6G4SXbhZGiVDFHyy/CoYPeaWdweML87HIhge4dAK68oFPArp0QlaRDW/itRv4BXkFCxCDBYdU40oiHcTkuOzdwWzDHoYdnY82zMi5OoPPgZLaDt/wAzzONLj8A1MeWx8@f8U@riAEfyaFASbN1QpZflSBGAsa31oCV2zqITuZa0H3TvQp7DXyGo3kVvjddkurxG1EC0Px6J2ngDc1IwBuHabmZUy/z4Ve/m@lXGZgn2Qdg@2Xf1gPzr3DzywyW9c0Dt2bpR5HAQ/J8rHniIc2R3pELjSx@BsCMWHguWCApmTGEojknSmNwngJ/SyBgZ3ASjc@hoIDFoJT8vf88Pd1pJvCUvkomg2yEzb9M6531CV98dO20vmKhmFcygKR0HgCk47X7uLGSA0wmK8D4wrkxqr1qA3ttbTERewN6rVjlpZlZt17mxFchousQVrgYIHINBnEgyiwG@NX9aNCcpJQkRkV5FFfiKIq6NrQz5I/tEdotnxAiSwCxOI10PK95gjdbec40OHWyjbdFRa5eWPcBSQq0MmRKioK/Xf2p7QHLzG3U59vVcfEdb9PwODeX39xGhz0iD8o3a9Nsl2Vwx4Nfv2Ss9xxULnu9eYyWrfgCQRwjiIq4iGUbL9mpd2o1M5w3GbDpj3yWjTKzBeZfyvSX8CzP987No/4S1w/qQ2Kx@8eWjd2efcgMS6gZNZdRislZlvL5hVnyc@QnA9nBA0jeQXIgmkBMdHTjtT1yd3b3Dr56@Oz4xnF2FDJ@PRhI8vpW6lSS041maIhHszVfJA/2M8dPHuwHBTFDuhiRwKC9@DlRVuVkNpqBIGer469nbRGG13O3HOMXfAvtdXxz6irUKNINPJTsR6RLK1Slfdpncj1xtbSIWoXCKpRm8DIR0Lt8k@ANVBPJy6tGc6t@asXiNzlhQUV4GZM3sBKA6dTdWM8gs9/MHGYsvGHxBK92cqN1Mbe4LorrOTxVCbcpe/bZ7Dwp3yHiEclvkAyISEHOBEGX1r5DrnXPTj1T@Q2Q/Pyl6KkzEYSL2VUUj4A6CS6TRCkyO7PRP65woLkD02gLwWk//NjC4HS18MRCflJPIin4J//zhBP@9ZKTykSm5SiJJEo7gpVmq05ADOAlBajQqK89G0NP75k94idB07TjQz0wHdkgfqH3Q@sXdPbV8RDC9ehzpNMQMEhuCSIDJeMhqlx/AinhH4A4SeERk5BeA49B9DMuD7uFxCQpD/RJ1@iDbE8k0yDRPlGUJgsPScRM06GIVlykMpuVwsqq@Clu/YyS/aNOypzMENAammxYXX2SiF/Ek5UmpI/u8YsX5/GkuIiX6MRO/wjL7vWjO0P0N5XVkkTz/NoZnIu5SFqUyzelBLhdB8zPnAquoSmX5YEr0G1iNdTFjz3nMRhBjUj0htqIJcYWP5dLZmRNnCasNB1kJNX50X4WS6WoiwQf8pAZxeyRibffCc2askSmBkyArq7Vxc9bY8Qaiiw3wUyJJNk6Xg@1CxoXnnGTFKBXC1EqBLaGLAQdB8CIVxKZMzjEQX8Bjx5y6HSzBd50Ww6NlNlIE8o1q99jkVu@5jVHsVyu@AU6LxXLDLjvpjiUMwD2hpwLdHmgrn@GBtAMOrSyEJsJ8psSL0bpxjgij/zDNwCdWOQ4zuBMDgawZodldgYO/hJ7FtQVPEao8vxkv1VKZkQWHuLRd4wujuTyE6XDTpt/BwhU08xc0HiV99E@xWh4OluLnxKCh4ftU4URr4nUWJQM1y/NnfGmoqzkej@iXwoQMo8NgL/TqRWAw2MIgzn1BX6Lhf3Pf47X8oqJdUU5aznnqXghW4WXUi2wAvtk/VSS1hvZ2v11DXpO3pvJqci0TH7j4bk@6LUP@plTUWQ5ls9kNuL7G88MtfjyzeQqp5TenI2UYkN@M2mKpVr6rDlhz5598b71PilOzqfiaYJ6k2z38J2o5LGzGquU2eV2MRc7K6NH8LzlH3XZc72XLsZFFjs9xet2xU0xk2nEm/BPXq/g4YEadbkubzffv082mKZ5kyk7jeEVluzwPnpTP4lGmlQ1eWwYRoadjtxuF372gDX5Pcwx/qRSCYn5DlKDu1WHkx65TXb0fn@8p025uxEb42ff8@M@@caLFy/Q8IIe9vYo5sPmEIM0Ki2tEGNqVv2zn65dpS@ftbb@7FvDjL6Gn0P8fPfqCZqPlcIna2ufPHiQz6eBNNz87BvPvr6zs5N/mC48axS281J2betP/2RtTVW31Mxa03WVZrxxdvaFqGbzovxnP463nj37muvWc//HN9/XFXxtwuucbYKcgCfHFDDiuwQ/BXWsM/YWnrMew38yv@1GzBqa2723LPY2BlyuxKb015oV8hpT6tub/@X7h29iXqyuZl448PVib2LFUowbwQC2XGA7j9VjWxiseBWbZmq1Ghg3/8u/hfj1rwIc9JluwateCGAVp7G6VKMo72L1IhgUVYV0/69vfjPCPFxM1EiNC577rAGPmN9Uxe0mPBv0bAl4dJqUzVDfG9q94E8p3VPuMWZ5A0@38WPwj6XjGdZSFXrdR41UKtWUWxI88kvquyuKegoCgM2xFtUQopJv5S4s6hbyie8Cfi9ixFPAVMRX3Ow7EKtxhxfXw71Y8FRf/GM/R0KsuHZff1ivgyjM1XMb9RQ9a6eVCid/hm2WRNu@D0IizeKnYpy9Yo/9wqmL2ZIqptPp@y0qBiSpNInNCMg4jVhsjrIxNrOxqFOMBdHYLMzHhtvD58//1z//wZ9/n/5@QL//gKfMWV2jl9mAeOdQder8ga9Yd8TLU7JAhrOVUqWUaV2dJjZAUjWPmJL99F28kIsfh0x5mgxGOGPhU6/ji/59G5noe83N96mHFgoxi7I6XEDUGDTB/mI8qXFeb0qoONWkhlIsNCXOj0Ee62XWuA/FJKqbZbFZVwvqIRSdIvKCG6y7zI5BD7IIkbbhWYM/@ocntK7hKPIaua0FPhTq5rMWpnvrAzAryoaayxQ@Ke6pQqzRyDT1JlRkVg@A3F@rrJUqxYqaaa2Ay6o3nXRdf@bGzhWl026333baGjxtraMpnnZf3pRLsro11ibaVPPa4/ak7XXGHUURYu8ba@yIV4MmSwXPaerW57kst3wjGWz8SZI9iQmxf4SnrqgK2wBBmoUXaA9khM4d/kE@WOwSnub7jcb7DeCQemqLqmezLvlYwkdu3W@mpKurBpirVf9/qx4aq/RwE2SueZVKbb2sS1LjZb2RApAvfZAyhym36s0t8gjT8hPzvbea8bwdL9r3GSSb2mps1exd@kFMeKQmwN2aw/X@/ZQMpvsAoL4OikQylVqXpDWU4Q1fVkHgZj0VZApxAO1mawsY4Grrqn7V2Lq62tqC/y16X/lfcL3auvFPn9mzJMzMv8kaObUEeNXrp41M/TRz6jNfE@xypo4ucuYUDHX4QjhozIQYVE@9IsQ22EZsxJTNXGxDiL368OX/jL/TD1/@Prb0DP6EWGYDOwhl3k@AF7OeWOwJfyww4y@wogs6PKmjo8Vf5MIymVcyq0j8cHylVEzKKAxbdq@F@1ll9uoJSD4QEExUS0WxlVKmKotticVNFBG/cOOJx@P/5JVa3ozz7jRuwXzlPomg5SPG6A9C/8Ki55/8wrJHiL2DrIJ8cxnPtxADYsckqS7E6ltDXI2HQ9cS9hI@r30hPd@RsFureTQZ0eFdttrBXq1crvNR9/VnxB0bDzfgrcD/3prr4k2kmMwlvtpv8O/xW/x74@HfSQf/jt7gHzt5i39HHv6xJ238e@bi38kb/Ntp49/JEP8evMG/Jx7@Pe/jnxCrsXVlXcma2U5WaSttMBgs67DsIDtQuqDItRSW1Vl2mp2y7NBWumDS4S8LJiPbY9k@y1pZCwKCL5g8lvXQ1INPH/56AMiBPwNXe7SVbIdBQiaqe3SlFYIH07vWqdCAfqv4SgddXFbkrFw0mngRQENsquUSk7Ek5Vbj1Wm8iSfMquU8a0/1tdNXLOaCHl@NZU5PM3xEgqn5Kt4ZcHXVau09fdhqZVDInT6xD2f/h4fDqHXl//DQfnJoD234Pzw8fML0eup@Cqr//fs1EAf@ZztWr26fVkioBIIlltnaPq3nJDQXUyArVHRLfeQzgwjf@tqpEH@RePHiokpKWPXivHpRJUNoBUOrGgbwg3EDOFZ95Q1cqoEWdwHP@QU54guNFy9OQxM3ZF5cnGJnBHqZ4T9ouVHrf4V/4/9d/0@esyRLNJrJxOXVVoKeJP4lk5dXl1f@u55MJHxLYgv@0AHsGOXyqo5GCnQJpkYi2UxeXXE3eCeSWxxgHZLZqlPcWTio/rEwSUqWvxL/db@QtP@cxqtMm60NOD2dZLPJajs4@BrnxbR3NEWbrNI1RuvthtL80x/T8ebbSQpUyFerygbjFjWvVqv5wLZZqlZLgWU9kSjffOrZbaUIKlU@n0xWq2DZDsBmwRqCLQHYwFIAqLqrdajSV2OXB4d08DfIiEIMT9bnQiGRpesB8KaZuFgR791L@DfYbu8k791Ty9l370KX0QiclDmnVqtrOK0WuufevRNbIk3Vlwtgz5bevVOy5ZQST9pO4ileUQRJJSSFfaLWKdWy7QAlNsGbKRl1hsdAczXPcxJvjVFaxEVrrpikG0SyWds5jf/se9/61mm8VhMlkVzzCgLAVFhha6uYr9eLeTAXS0Aqcf2SX6bTT5WV5NV6RuTkYOJ6POZ7KaXNJJeMcfSHdpRt16F6u/iwy6sYlTvLF5IJkK1J0NGuYvjHnZVymbsnWb6YKKXK/l9tLcnqoDDwP@wT51L5jc2N@01Gf5OFD4rk6qVeU65ql3oFxxavqh3/hkjc56rfu5crA11L2eqp0Go93DnZabVqoihiiwgvdCThLuDFVCMn3qAyL5SbDcxh8zQer1TvE38opQIDRvDDSXFoJVipTIQQjB5uYofcC4o/4rAmqPTFl1D2xyHAMYZNMv914WFd1mZ9fFifGYbBDGbSw0zG/end6YSBbP74vqGV4uITuujhI8SePd7Z3TtJq1sSi6n7O7tp9fj5g5iC1sLMTt45tB/t7Tw8fA4Rnj3e2zne@/Tg873nz8DdZRezJxD0/nv2jZoW2C/YC@G181bTdU0f63rrYjy@eMNeG0bLgPIzx5AJu@8wV28B7iNtlo8q/DqGq71@rTkjetiHH33nw4/@mw@/870Pv/OdD7/zg599@YPvwO8n8Pse/37v35QL@P7Zl//8dz/89u@A43@A3x/B76c/@/I3vsl/ZP9j@P2niNsf@79IOP4TANYv/@zL7//4Z1/@yg/h9y/93w9v/n71p4t/P/j28h/G@/7vrg7zvX8Lv9/jsIKw3/tt7obfG@F/m4f7lR9@@PV/x///1P9D4@98@PU/xpdv@Wc//NP/9OFb/15VS3/6rz98@/sfvv2tD9/@7odv/1P1w2/8ayUbff3uhx/8wV/94e/91R/@D/T/E3r/3l3@P/zwn/3F//IX/9tf/KH/@yn8/h2YfvoX/x7qxt/@wY/w//t/8Ld/9CP8/5/@1d/@wa/97S//j2T4TW74v//lv@Hvv/7V//g3v/Xdv/rpN//m1376N7/5B3/1v//K//kb//Gv/9vf/@v//lvo@Js//as/@uW//NZ3/vLb/@Ivv/Xlkvd3Vr6/vIP7l/8ILnfH8y5w7pKvj3X58u@Fzz@EGrNUgE@Au3/pw2/8IjD4rzP24Ts/wUXh8Fvy/xNVoTA/4bb/DxjUm3lGnyyY4PdrH77zPSTRfwckgv@QXt8NLXM@3PLdmQXI@lsLIv3Sz778Fz8mW0yv1Gm4GpvrklpKbUCXZqNc9ptsfyQbovziPLQQgJ/Sd1FCzfl9F2Xbhx9988OP/@mHH/3mhx/9MjaYUr6c3klLyup1lNDCSoU7hMOAxbuEw4BfYPopGrORUl@AjX3he37xxRdC610Gdx/cfweuX5ATfxj3wt0Jvlfgh@64XYG9Y1Gzb8z6xnXfNUyZsMBUU6RobARaUCHHJikfIZwloC@4Q6DJBhkn@CZX9J4I@Jr9z4wTgaUwDH/wvqbASAY/np8ENwoFSCY1mQTkIrWMcVVog7vQxBilmy8zzMFkkppAfxcMkEIKvB6kWK1WS2HEGscHrBy1eokRKqlUDfKNsXmcdKuEICYPCArErKWOWGujNuERUwivHpAjJaDTkaioYqpUewgJ1iYPGcJC4AT21atavVSb1BHce06P1CT1gHBCYLXUpP4e7DWCCfGE2MP3gEqplkrVS5ggZpIXT7rFC6lAmaO8p1jKLwP44ljz9n3GPhGVktji2iESjIfGd2oWeptmDbfB/zS14WeH/gMj/TaI4GuUlJ8K4/7bpIhuc90UAwBcSZJlmcEPpyK32X3wnnBQKUoWPikOIUUcQRwQOjAc8EkJKSrfFFkg/Vht46MfBIaZWV9fF2J1MSceykS6TIY5ZxV@38473veqMLFYFtFZp7XsAS4Qv0rpr8dxhiDOOGD2SYr/7t/fYJ9ANuk7cxOYlMrZeTvGoWylUqIK8Ot2SngJPRAB@JQAvRPkSY3mxFJCOs2YXIuhHzs8PPSRIIeXNSEFbK7mFLTjJMZ4PI5BDFlOy@m0/5XpSw6yb5DJ1//K60hcGsZkqpqvQkepytCJRXs1CvSA0fH9@/dQKrSgpHIAnVPmry1R8yXyBAe@@do0p8GeBzVfFnjHnCnFPGMJuhcTniRLCizBNpICX3rMkQieRFwtleIUDqgvJzaCpUZFhdgBhy9jdUQ0eHhnsVRIBp67h2z38MmTvacno2aTCTrdWaq3Ro7d0V03gX47Tx/y3QdquZiMNRoI@qSiooAR9ipZEn8HD48OjiuMZ9ovggQhVqUJIj@bZUWIjUYvtmL@UgsRL8ixxWN8V2Z5S6jlHESN1YVYR8ceBfAS/sOvKjxx@w/sCfT506KYVorYjUvSoC0Tvm6PGZ7dxjd6Q53Cxejy1hZRQKhfSjR8jkYoraJQr/uLlJgi1I/3TiDCySFT1Kws1L9gExkTlK6EulkzdavvDdZxtY94mhUjeVpvZNP4p@Zy8FbyxbRS2GyurZmXEqZ5SsV2icu2rsB6KWE2vgIPE74isK@AEzyQBq7FYv5CuIPDqr8aCU9JSfAlSaJSgGqWFE6hoDk4YRR9qiNgb@jVR35CbO0b3/BYvQ59aelgX4iBuBiwYEWOZHTlgUzl3B07Ovn2Gesanxt49ZHcNdyRqU2h7gA5YldXVz2AdLDP1LpKVh6ji@@rDrm0wXw10YSYVanU3iv5TSGvVirvc6oqgIMQe/lS0@r1RrZ5md9U84V8Qc0Vi4VNFYhWzhcLpVxWyRazBVVVyvl8uVTevGIJKFlNk@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@IVZOFU5w0/RTEMrQkFjsMW6b9Gx2Ytt0FeEDvbMkxO5AowWCu47tuv@AMA8064x7PTT4SWWh1yMN7yBxh4Y3WBLi@WiIOzh15x8Nwt6wDQhSxaYAD@DlmLa9KMAme/5sSS6fhGeDAjH44aAQ/Ojg00cnke/J3s7uI6HIHhw@fXjtU/ADFdjjvf2T0LrJfYOohRDE1/ceP75u9T/5w@dHvbHt4E/YP3yen71CJ9xzJuThmQ8UOhMQ/4VWUltwiHqNFTYDgyLgquV70PW65xsLxZkxi8YXfEOd4YaraPnOyYpwEuyy0xgKoLbOOnyjLvYF6cgbX1NUNsuCMGKWfcE2s6xrm6aGV7v21sBxoOHuIR3VJZNuIMakL2zH7F4YXX1NeIIblcoK3l@JSAiPAMhw3KHzJQxPwAPUunjpKk6KtM2xzsZ4sfESR/igExodoz@ABubCDgIIbU1jtE7m4x6Ir0cfb7WDx9Mgtxs@5s3gQkzQPC1Wqt67pzxzoKbUs5VKX6/vTYBN2XOoNpozTZcKotwR95ncivWNhtscQUnl8kVlAzUtUG/XTrNnlbw9qmsutESpfAOUQ6/XqUL7VqgAheul7fxutuCI5Zy4nhHFR9pf/9ZP/u5Pfu2IlUDYbWTgFVNEEZdLrymCTGq0Wi4VSuWcWkqXyqV8QSkWCmlFTUMPZLMMSmhWKSnFUqGspEv5cg44sAy@hfKmEONr0TIbBBK@FQBrdfCGxS3SxOUBqNx8Woy9TWhJFtNC@5iJOsQRBez0eLQfc4MZNWhrmJJluU0GIDXWYbH9/d3s/r4oPkALLgTYzYpiFy2FUja7@UAUdfLZLaEGIdo8TglPqhE9bslmH@yK4pgDwENeRXGAlr0ijtuIooGW3Z39fUynhxYV40OwM@7DLWZg2YRgFlpyOQ7gTQgNgu3wdPKE6B5aMEn02ec@u@Anip8G6KDPEQ/GATwKcrqzI4oH3LKzgz67lO0CR/QztOzQI4oOWKA2iGIfDH0H6qEotsGIdUIUO2DqTDVww@ss8RxQy9NEccrJgwQSxQmF1jpnotgK3DGZz31sCkjdClkUnuv7ZCnjnyiqAdIYLBdacqKYDy15yNujR59rA6@r9/kzdfi3Azl99CinGZPx3n7700/b/X7bme7sfXqEXru7j6C5n46ddr/tR2y34LEh1u4jVTsbTq8/kOuDVquimQu9Pmu18pp1zas1bemIIcR6A5j5Tx8TGrZ2wWv3Ueu@tmiKkgC2UBwM4dvG58EQvg@0NvcKHvKi76TdFqvI/6ga013XUBXp2un0UOs4dhXtk9oaY/FEPD1tFLPNKnmwISjB2eoVXXKdwLeG4wzJy2ljUss2a5PapspXt/QS4ulELRhiem24rZQLlTVtW1HzqUkFN3vbvTiLS8o2Syj3Nt6yxNPktprLV8TT7W1JbCjNbVUpVYqbLzfGopis4Hs7t1mBgNk4dNLxlWxsNrc3C5Eom5spLaNWNjeT1Sughwftexv7/61E4kLXzpJJRBd7o5AFfsX2lPJpVHuJSXpS43ixabI6qSlVfvQdy96A1cVzVscdz3Y4xD6Am2xnK3SJt6iUSyKkn8kkkkkQeCSb4Dtb8PbiaydnJydfgCiErrvfS37Gb4at@tZPH@3K0HH2bXg@qryPXRDbkXdRXs358OM7A6cT0NPlR9CgQi8lcMMNOI5tynuTjj7CfkzgEZx6J/tnlcknj@bgHA@g67Hvd37cKh2hYXV0hsfHGl2m1epg0rosQVgxLXlBTXmrXq@1akN@D3c9jPUZo7NVZ2AOXI57uKuaol/iphTfo1XLXlXbtUlsAnBaNSYpr4Z295Wa6lS7eGrsg9oDjFxtwbdd1Ws63kYuxsRqb9uqMTa2XK2nP9MdPCPg4HAdFAvcqZLoMT25zk7p7vJd1OavpLrDrBlmT8fDBPTU28l5p4gVSZP4WpDlS9o6hdP@V9VejSVeJqtvwOqss0RXfpDczle7iQeslQSX7Kveqx5TWTFfpescEwgJKhHRhu4ET9bqn4EuxAGfVSqAiF/GZwATUwKwRpc8tOTIuKp2aiZLSGzCkkSefLVfa2Dsd/jakkSxKUmNd02hLkkvhDrU0@o0ptXccZuOGmfZtqJmi9UJuCmb@eoAClZ7Oak6tdHY0asmWP0hI75DTKsCOYFqAObtu8SHX/xmcksq1LhblUC9M0H9aMmt2qRq4eFFwBK1XA08Uo18Ng29XHhtpqGdV4tppZjOpfNpaRNdoZFPF9LgCD0dUC0SZkJkTExnJ1lZSSu6kk5kXxndV8n0WQLUFyIZS6Y9ew@vQgcXKCTkSrLCV2PJlLphMigFm2lbErEpSIoqZgxoPmAjIz1AUEe6ZlKMZFJiuY2EuZ7AMOsn49Feo1mp7E1GXwOvhPRmu5jazKbeJpPVxFqyBmqQUK8KdZQqlOvRGvCsP5rG3PGwAWUMJmVTrTQabcziZjady@Ygd0brXX9LrIvNdHatqEARXTHSjxiXGFxHmmk5M7cWKuCmDiWnlNWqINMCEUpSSahlNSngGkQ/pjDyxRpSkiVOxWA3ZCIe31Tj8WS8imPda6I/uAmyjORYHIRq/J6yLYICJlbEsooBZiKRNrxlozrYlYCjAyxfFmKXwtXl1RZ0bzO0JBCUSbZGJkmu3xdiFcZAETz1j1TJrDH2sSsNU1v1l/x7iguYAa5AxwyCGkorgHQD@2Tsc9zcu83igJjmDBuqmms21E1oyUA6BkFVVani@H4Ml0jLdSCxewn4baXquC/mMzadaikpGHC@x1g/tS5QpmPX5/B2ajv9o51qYNvFIcxTQRTFalyMXcZj8Sv4E2L3aTOOyjfjsFhkOw6OYeMYMdDnfYxkA9u9DIaeKnjZTUKrcEnQaCbfPzXMy1JO4uMLIJqurmLrGSoRf09D9bNXagHKyLKDTQ7QJ8JxHGikCgUcf41lXo3cb6il3JODQ@uhs68zvsWhlG@J9RjLKhJuGahWfNeC2Fo7U4AXcmLuLB1j92O0zFksl1RR5Q7VGDuT4kqFb4sYHZdfbr4svXzy/PD54b4QO117t2bjUDsLyMTeW1/9GgSM5/Jxxk5rsUktX/UXgdXrkrKl4uFFm6wCYr6nFKXsuzpn5zp5FFXw@fCLP8xPtkpgV7MK2FW1kFLrdWVDZcnY6MOXv4@nVlzufb7zmMVdbcr@7k9@rG7@3Z/8K1pYFb@qujQwvBmDkGhUipuxy8vR5eUVPNyvEGvGOFL5zSSY@QSCEqtnFDVnWVaVVTKatrGZyqv3rWrGD6tsKsmYK8X8qZDNQsx953up2RJ4BXMV5CQWsUhie0dGQVXubyGTKOGOLRb@beluGbik9OTVO8bA0ql3@31DJVMmwyrvJbb1Xtpi73F64L20xl7V6ji9rOA@r2D0fAP3s@AUUryeymzEGfR6WL1xVW2mGI2/Q4fxpa5vWKfXWPx0DVfRzzttWPCnb7j0h5ECBxesgU3feO2KiY1kJtPt@mccbemsUAdW2MgAZqfJD7/4G6pa/Ls/@dV3rXetL1ToFZbLRUWN/Vz5@c8hwIqzBoIuHU0z4KEAaAi7gmzJxejQzRViYwtVXx4@6BhiVxAVB6NvQfcebcI5KjtUSi1@gFU3MeY9RlAE06Q60/EyyaoghComqcZOv5MmGGwDL62AaitcCl9BL2hRWQ0kqfCVGShwGEIbandarjl2RrSxIEHxlGaa3YMokMJX8GywNdpC7YtjCSRYZuNmVI6yS1QjxYgNddfFk8agJRG@AlH8AwbxLm4Nd/tjSMMC@S9jEMKTPLoNSLsJaZs8QotcE5R7HiDNOHY8kgXqs/AV0AiICgYoCszYggBVkDlfAQJAHhI@YKPJtlguyS6NVKo6O8bsClds40FrWrDTWMBoCK2LO9uDyFUMB06gtuOVVsgXfgmDjhZxDIBwGHzStwaKP0YnG2pedBTAnUEBLDp2J0FZY/fuzbCq1YxuklGOEP6ZMcJBLCoHazGuACzoNH3SrYhphgfEVQPXkO2A4ilCF7hO4ifDVSNRmYjWK0GA/zszLXLktaIijypmwC8vXis6QDKIjGTnZdhhWzWmqJtJFiLfAdw7hBQdShb2BE8nn8jqF4HnFWD481hwYDwIopPowKDPt9e3mjNoEcd4WjceOMSFgb9FnB8phALtwAtih7EgK4ZJoXuGA70Umo0OzidL5JQkRpud50Z40DpsNc9wOXQhiR@KhaEZfDU8ictPZ41OE@nYUKDuyLbo6C46ZgSXmgNHgIzyT0DiaI@tC7zdwS8bihzFyKXTj5DzEWM6ioyuxaS4OB3cdqArG9AmzfS@zDrDLlPLLEGMRic1WSG4JEUihNug8iKN26Y@BJSOdZ22ALmVTKYPCtO4TcdVPTGArwb7BrQqlpvxbyDNXBhnRuYET6eW7B7uFOKb/2OoY2H14zPP/tFQpm2fMdM40/l4b2Lu6ASXgdIPimsaKDv7AWEruKRBzaVZFrzTPBT8NuGzyY2ldCTuWmKavPnNKWuJFpboO2pkDAdvFz3XrAh96Xkn@P1cd@oGh6/QESJgl0ORq/vHLtTiuKE6PE9E8I@RqdEJJjLOI4wS0OsMjl9BI@jj@jnDHquAbQwIzU5wkAHWYsjtV6gBoLoHNQtPYvOcCh6/AZg43UQHqp4v4C32CcupAgbkZ@P459gADCz62jx08IOomA/X60LByHzLGsgVqJ3DLvjhxm@f/TB@wN1oplPyZuzN1nxw2OhQWjXGq0VgKUQsWDuQnynra@BZBAwXYLKWEFMANiUmRQ46jH89Oud2gWRJhd2ElGYIwSc1QCFVIbh@mEWuYRDA44Hm8tM//TPbLi4uZDo8cOwYsu7i1QQu3qmcGfUNUJftjKcPR/4lcAZe/unDnZkkfiMJ3rS9PaE7rsv3pvwrCD235i8MScR7bhwbx3M8eb8/pEOH8LQflxhq36BbOzoJf50K5z@1mb4M@K@C/CeV4lcIhDEEM0lP0500AEu3O2fp3kW36nucU4UE4FCKeuCIB3Y6gWXoBiZj1AtD2B7t6wjsbfOM5kQBksjHZWdJ8xwGIaeB1bePjAlEsvQLtuM42jRB/kkMjQycmJLaw6bQ7JMPGKGZYZf89Ehj0pg256JPwujQqAW9IebgiULC5Wqg/ChR9J9w/wn4T7j/ZJZokGxj0uQqGTpdYXaQ6/EguiAkgpkGYa74sZszH4IMOjZTOAgMOZ1zu4Jfp0axA3pzG5RjLWAM4IkREFxPZBovTxunTcvVLzaaqUwfmF0kQkCJA@hGk2h60Q3NSH3z3BzZ7pyThecPQqvk441OnYHPDZxXMI9hARFjcHoZeGRcf@ivJeAKgZ9hgIB6GHiiarDjJYxkNTy6ljyBcRrijMYcsYaPTJO0L9/LdwN1iZOeEzYKqBkBhO5hlgBN8GFBzeEX0QTS4YVjQ5ggrER3Zwzx6KJ4Mw6UvFZVuKypUiFFsJKkAE0gO6qrtetZCfyhKBrXvCLZvPLLP4r@2kej34N6sRh7YljeYFSFaFXBVXCgQvjVhajK6rVIuQIGmQ3N1B1oufa4fuq31pDMRiboZvB0MAvuBd6um4gUfifJy4e22omWWAlZYVqrQRanNV4teb0ISMoJHkZz/WjTgBH8@FyAAIzswmi6H20SjTap1bjgYJMl0S4iSE4IyQmPwkNPliDZ9KNB7ym8lh2LpwnaKS7TEwGewptRUINGIsMrdnFq@zUeq4YzoH6aM5lDXODzEKrYyGed5sLUGxGkI0LrGgBkxBsAuvxOu4pwXeApUmgLZRQnZSCjuM1nAy4rgMFIBFf50aOJkMmoDwwKv5iidgDqrphqCKJCg7v4l@U/MR04Bj/lpmN2PqQy75hNX/v7R3FsImUjFTSifSjZPApk7Mk8t/wz@6I6Rwyvfx3YoNW1L2yWWKBsg3tm7EfNtE27nRlquEQFb7ryb38eTZNB/wEnRtj9ke1pnp3PV3inySC2W5Q@7zMYfcvGA/IjRw6Drte1ddeKe1CoHbtvGa6eZngy3Jnudzt0/4RzIaon@0bbFQR/eJJ3YxE05ytUdVstvHuz1UrgArtkJVyuS@vtkD3jcQH7v2CKxAfx5AM9HCXs9mu94yVvh4mnY/vRTozOWeJw5HvGIZEdBjKsA/o/@A5Ag2GuPes50jm9qEq3vQSd6j6wh3YftL6xKwsY@xr4gxlsREgbjQiXNNOwS1uJnJFOtSTRSWtJP@pnHx2VfaYmtGQYX50HMEeMNHOu0xgp6yxIrrU0OR4tSO/44/E9juJ7vBpf6oVfx5l3zWvc8@OSziVmECDgDI3c7Whg1kFudW@gM4dK6Ix6FY9wZxS7tASsi5juQNAdP7jcA/5IhzYXbCHiny@j/@oCDKLv3bX4NLyQ@HgK8maIKxMTdEuCG8xwJiD4QTIpxBYkF7L2wzumBWHxOql9VCFAjSXBZeERo1AxR9DtdsOD7wPAt/A8rrq6wfe0FKvGPRfg5Jyn2Zm6vIgetrq6qU31bsIPmY7ADXJ8BB02kld3yzgKOhJ6Nu/rJaDtSoa@0Iwj0XmgyhKW0dLnyeRytuJBjJB7aKScMDxYTj/0vyGacYivxkeroR8Qj8dwOPbcwOHP0XQ05adYm/wqGl@O8vaHlySeJ3A7QYAO/hE66VmyyVXi8ygRZukOLUIYVp7PMh4yG0DEg25uluHHkej2nELhRiLVglIW5m9kWFzixqoSj3BFwJN8CuluLHkb092Z5yKsxoHNRNjuxzUhNyDjooxOJxGFyF1Wlpht3ZAJ6EbjdNaSVqW1QKCGMUnSeQZ1t0m/SArYMz6ALw44fQ5fBNjXvRZnqCBvOKbl3zrDyGeojSJai@8CSjpAiVCRk9xHIxJKCMwQ/PIqTLOzNM3OjTQ7c2mGNWA@yUggoTOXpF8KWDyrisDUe94S6Yxe2HeGzyqxDY9law6OVlzGjXjFSLP4ebwCAjmuxyt7CRDK8W688pAMbrxyTIazeOUzMMzqVvxdvBJUCwzggJUM99HdF@Fo78Qru4nkleBpZ7obpCvHK2GZQphtbiWKACkw36A14hSbZfvZ9BwdGjZSKtMMOcZNY/eJxmHS9MvCP79jhe5qQE8c49ygwCzFlLlGI9Ji8HSg2QjOAl9Qkyt@a753uE@LmsIgmEwK@njROAQe1PBYfF4YccTQl2Y04AsIotysLMaIRVqyO6Ljpw4cSoU8nz5RTyZ9oJsg/wYEbs4SoYt1/PhBec2D4AV4Nzwx8jI8b6ATJEcY4ZxscgFaSNRX8RWZwrKex8Uv/WgJ0Vj3fCC80TsIwkuJwEZkOuhwNDmHiY3s0TyTkC8upDeicWhQjldK5N5r0Ugq@DVziTc5@zlDwRCt/MlV2YnEQ9TmRBB6NrJNXsvCdoFkMXrNZF1EU@WVD1CIyByo4XrnjC4teugbKRwXN2lqK5Y1Q0FcniRJrnkxCZFlPBhprHk89bDzuofHJX1c9zWIOcGxlgQCiMQMU@Hy1f4I/d3m@nugUAdEuJbAIsV6cVN6U71e2cpew9ycJXuzANEzzR4mFypHYQozkkPvIKKZr@K1Gyo@LvngSj5PNIR@TdsPyBb2CW6h2/W@BYeFWoJzPu94poLjmbqcUDc1EvNcDpQWGVPy4fCMh5jOsrYaV57xRUWMPjS@rZkfXcDOfAFHCw/hUQacayTntdwZW7TKZVa3QWxzFxSpSoVxQU7TpWExzxxB3NPUbThtCw6HraOHh08ffx0a3c3NzaTfRk9n@GGtxbHWsB3nkGmFdNgeLOi2qGm8hwQnu3E43h3Yjrd2aok3ZAkX1qAMaJBKwH5@HU/6siwiz6/VXYjHw0Yo6sM6m1UDbU4qoaqjYZNt@HT1gCC6l9jQfCCBegv0TlNvLUk3brRaeGN6q0XNV6uFi5daLb8Vw6IJZsSTP4@tZcauQ7dI8utiLgSBDiJgDw/Zi0c7J@zk0R7bf777Gfv64XP2YufpCe5Bf/b8weODXQa/vafHe0yYWzmJV2thhxLo@lDv6HgDIp4ql2cEedceTbncSewmufuxNmSP7I6O01Rbrja8P@AW2dK9Oo@1B93RKY5hGnR92tDwcL0F3f0F3VhUbrq0@Q8X9DMI24Y@7RD7vEO7a/QMCCtg33dk6G6wX4yZBpQgyNtg82@aK0l4zRctHaIL@XAF1gVE1yA8zt0AGI2vv6JL6Q2XR9C7MvMJFz4fTcGTvaMnxwyPM9g9fPrw4OTg8Okx2z88Auuzrx88/RToeXB8cnTw4Dl6UcAnhw8P9g92d8iBI5CVGZ4z8HrseitRkDE4UaVzhjPf8giKP7TNj3qjBs8uNNoG6bL42ELpY2im8VbvxqvC2EX1Bbde0lQBS6zvHH36ObT5TH@DM5zBVDCtPxCfu3Td3HqWbVFqUFnqUN@qfnWFZk9SkjQfMZwyvH1Cr9L5Awkyp1kAnBbxdA2dibu4RgXHvvkxBVSXA9CQ0BrARlDBgpUao1tj4vH0FoGsQ2od08YjJXlqfBGhb8Go94OlJlWBKOavlUGguGnhwMLxIKUaOgDfg4PqJ@s5PADLhQ48AMtzB1RFD3DtCCv4Icbe4RjFMytyh9fD0T5NC7PN0OGBRr3Yko8TLzcqUo2Ft27hoQ0m3Q3ER3nozkLN7RgGRXEpPN6bY5q8Yuj/T3FPu9XGjuRv@ikUm4RuaLdtEgjBmMSASTxLIMNHcnMMcRq7bXqusX3dBuwE7pndH/sCu//3EfZV5h3m1z7Fbn1IanXbEO5kz5mcE9zdkkqlUqkklapKfGMbyEQ@SiTbNsiZAWHTxqMGafbGV5tiKnAD2gn57VEk7LLjiWM0Dgp6Id/K1On6PTaBik13iPfEGsbHKW/K5YO@zYjcQAZ9YkC8SS2Jhy63I1eFwWPLQcmtqRp9aSNJNwoqE7QfIbA1hcA/AgYA5RI7nSbNVOSZimD6bcnKdtQHjkS97e9mfmDn1lUzSBSQVlv2X8Jv3xxJZDexT1J2ioQddNG3YAjLSjrKbPeHMMZJrNL9LygFmxf9wSjkPrSTLaATJ5rmIDdObFDbV0VcWRvSIV1jr98zKj0HLr6n1nNgysfUShzPZ@dafMWXgQLnwyTMdneIjn/evw6MszMXD5FuAlS/wEKYzspR@TkZESa8/rRi2fG7wPsE18qbO1unud@/unipIIsFvsdTGR3if2BMrAuGB53zkcHiENddcqSpy6Ciq3MsLW3wpLTEUa6AwT7wIoR93ZtGSaexufH0d3SUSX@nj7e3ZS6VQ8kkr3aNLuxYurmirqp0qcyZkCYghuwEZEHW2@qLSzC1vH6DzjHYCyWgSA/lCO7bU1ctSRGiWnd@1QbJIm@8lN2t4Ttikywq4guA0enF7I/8F3urvLTp5GODEmGQ01Yi2lWQi45jmKXQfDUFbudhcCC/Hw9u7UHseHr4Q9B2HoT2h3DLLd0Pi6clA9bjwf7@AFie3P4hsNB2937APElOQ9OcrpnTnc9qa9qHa/w61Xc09gAMzr2oQdFAjdquenRErSI421zAMcHEC6Kj453q4aHI8P4EyoLcwy1DS4pBhP1EfIitbcMeCTtPL5r0ZlkvntSXhEWb@vfQYJ5JvHtEhVyDuJIeWljEV123wzFLPTmz0BKCrO9JICrKJbH7rmRQVJeA72APCMjGnWY00JrZzCxPPmFkGoFLurm8NjZt@MnCmuduvEdyODEBmTZBfgc9S2b33ydeH6@reniBheF9sMEtWEnDfAP7hCOoeAAZPS/Zgw90i@pSNLLnBXZW0Q4NvwrJFfbPMxQxEi/CeS1siHW5OJao8fp4Xi1zyCARpwEfLT1lIls0Q4IS8fRlw@xQJ5707OQUBItMvFnwjckVUPzsrqTvurfjebKsF@TmWJsnbOoKyzPUzkrYpfszPUVb6NW0eEhXBdL2wapy/z9V8SyRqEnRfGZjVCJAXl1Zef4j2OlWqOK5n4XNc0hafo4uB7C/j0FGk4jU@8C5tX1XpccM8ADp2LReDZhUQVjqzJhTEm2nycjED3BhvRAgg@HM8bLGdK2OGKdwmw2dZyQTOmWZaoMxhHVDedRMUf/u4epQIP@wvid/vD4ebJgJTQfv0Cr/fX8YBbFXnhGhxfiErq3Jb8Fw2KNs7M90iVBscmN60NmOvO3Y4JVbhYl03ma2pC29k9js1lW6BqqE1Ise3s@K2r1SWr2XK5bMpu7W9qpikcIcthO6yMww4xiy50nYewgBksGkl8Dpg3z4nkbr8B9wcBVIIBN589lEG@eHuBFFYNVcp4tspFmolK3FdO@3o6bfw7gebuZpJDLuMyhIWtjqwa4zS7NeKCXKA3LRoGdDKTeT8zJUFL6hQhchJUFwb@J3Y8JCTw1lKYnuNZ0@2kfhwVYwZu0ZWU76@eJaYfWVRa3ruSP3sv7qzF1sljMCJl@/dxldDW9av3b6F9dt0RWDv5yPm5Nvvwmx8kI8x@s4n3Gs2eJqOU/hPV/C3zXxqkCcKxF8TXFzTzNCeHyTnxALIt6Hl54IvsWONs3r6CGR4lKxeKm4EF3sRuXL@upZuVculC7rvbMSOvmNlsqjpeKSjR@ewSwKMoZP5uujM5xTTa1r0LsWeMErXcQnXUMEuYbAl/f@MOzvVfbfJrRxuABAFZi09SaFOt/NOofWbOh74vWCG1uqyVyBHGvhAsmaI6@gIrq7kz4Z1TGtEDCDXnFhNRuN6e/EseYK3tVg1KcUFXgQWUvchrfWnHJjKpBGAbLUQxWekK6kj8ZxHhsPhvjrhK2oc0VerhXRd9IxQNSxJInDzGkmgz6FiKj05aqfWZEX@M0LRAIvI76lYmJjg64mBlaLPNLioSmHPySHicIZPuIBCPwM6LQBq6CVe0RuHxY0H9@L@MBfSEc1Ij8ZMpC3aKWIKWj@Lb6TfxOV3wACMOHneM3lSRWnXHnBQpJ9B0m5gOHLkht/PGZAt0rulDlsLMLm@soxcLIUJxphtZJM8H3uBsnJtIJ/sgW5Ir1NNUPndzg7kYTOqeVbhLSkLqWkTfzpxsVso1hOFVOZDVLM/ZAaqOmC7dH7AIbVRGwH3S4gzbSYi8mBj@TfK@tf0vVHdazzTCPP6bmp9Fwi3eN0RirO5cEEH2daNzNlst/jfHciE2dzp@oqC1q8eNDTTQ@WJHHe0kN5I2/Ub4Rx5k3dlcyVOmEjkZAzUr7M6H1OeZIooxlcp9c5XfL3sux5jWUi75tk/fhryQ4KyHhW2pqkuNTrhd3XlrzHVqYgm2WAmkJwcexvYjselNIHU4oTWMGhnp@G7WY5hrJUVBKHxkxmc@NNxpOLjNd2Gg32YpwaWDPGiEElqnOJCDcmh0Woh5KfGCAIJjKaUCN3UxWeyMITAyzmeqKqZS/IqQEOTUsP8TL6Rd7iHzXYk8ipfNnZiXOM@Zgbz97NSQKR0H2SmU2mpDRBdxH@KBv1wCwS1z1JQ5wtJPYNLbCuM2Af7DaqwZ9oOWEKCiUppuiuUySl4wxFxb73dSEm3ln/m1@03vqwxh50g7Go4DbDJy8sK@HgPgqiUYQBnihMTXQ1GHTx1JEWfDfkQi1jhiyv4HFLDNGY2T2rhpY9nN/FJ@mQDoU8cYCQb9BAJE6IrjoddCZDD9j@DYpW1LiEI8@q9Cas0IAx83yZ3cwDcRXxqSns9jsmEtxzPHqQ0tHAbwaeBWu0CFY/Fje1HcprJEmfjn4jGEIMprR1y/rzVdj8dfstnue@LBaeFw2SXcvj4IL3/EXsYAVEUgnLGP5vpfjCsoyz4SafDecQoCv2cKL/CLwZXAe9XmBVYMagjBEsWqNgeB20PMs6DPQhMMJFVsaTSfTD7l8Nm6zcgUWXD8yIXsKRy8dhwGH4i/MzHxc36azMtfDQKj5thq6@DltIQOVx0u7j6TAdWGCYAKYHFroMRkCURUckUaKzZ4kLrV0uUREF1MA4J8bZhCZDrz8Km9AzpMmyugCKj0HiynqtFCZQX7Pro3OwNwsBdI@JKaAQUEdJD@FgyUPzP4SDkA1TZ@y@6pk8SL8@jRUY7sEwBOkbE5h6hYoZuEMHH7@rHYmjg93jT5XDqoDnD4cHH2s71R2x9ZnOuPGgnGLrincHeyBd9Gk6n5ofwIdM5QhKZijBqux/FtVfPhxWj47EwaGovf@wVwNoAP6wsn9cqx65ora/vXeyQ6fvAEHsHxyLvdr72jFkOz5wqVZVzIrLiYNd8b56uP0OXitbtb3a8Weqcbd2vI@V4al@RXyoHB7Xtk/2Kofiw8nhh4OjqsCGWTu1o@29Su19dceD@qFOUf1Y3T8WR@8qe3uphh582q8eCjISMFq5VQUsK1uwhcWaqJ07tcPq9jE2KH7aBuIBgnuuOPpQ3a7hQ/WXKjSncvjZlUCPqn8@gUyQKHYq7ytvoXGW/QOqQL9snxxWMRQSUuLoZOvouHZ8clwVbw8OdojWR9XDj7Xt6lFJWHsHR0Swk6OqK/C2PaoaYAC1IB2et06OakS32v4xzBknH9DewYFO/gSEASwrUHSHCIxmENhaINLB4WeEinSgDnDFp3dV@H6INCVqVZAKaFGxfWxmgwqBiMdmM8V@9e1e7W11f7uKyQcI5lPtqOpAh9WOMEMNDTI@A@tApSfUauwnwIsfgVktxbkudaeo7YrKzscaYi5zAwcc1SS3ENm230maexhp11CihH3UGfiXpmKlPf3pOsAIk9Mamdk6Gh0xaftgpwozsoxblYkTTmDWWUuFUjLTYKbRifCaCFnTCs6vOo2w1@6jj6kuxoqPy6jj4sUyDt7KcWo9cK@S1K9QgWy20fhYacBG96jRcNzHlEyg8aMSUg3@UC5HthEvFcCdNyp@1teZ7hsJQm0@kwedZKiHBxCYk6n/jE3f/MvAEfl8K5DF0HkfASvVUcTHJhd4lAKikZwd8TqRuErSTNB7KNmBCtoKvNdsoJ4ULSMpUz@CP73b@IUnB@MDSGdWd@XzuIklNMJvgaqGK6GQCPRHRiQI21SlFwXBrx27YFaHe36v0@@3bMdRZSjvCPaBHdv5QfHzoJMqnkuXJ2Tp2FnG8o/UvpuWMPr8WZJMyH7xhtQyG/80RvTjKGw45gNqTakqUlZLpaX9jIujRZIrZGgLdK@gTsY13/vKL7VPuJsrLL8opb6/0995bKG9IEaihQmvTuXO6OfdGWeAAUaxOIAkoYyQkc8bZZS9ic58AxkvMNNN2ELLH5irLwKa14EksJC98rtmnTgbD8OxiT3I4beHlfdbJ7u7IDoR2xdrKy9XS5YOu/WLy7@fsR4KF0tRxwYwj8M6jZKMUbINCx8aKWacbs3@xMD5PGbEmOyq0@gjxnnQdhtJSyYUZNjcCO/W6aGJXiZAOmQEBeB4Yil@nTkyJQPYiaY62JpLf0xLfB/WSsQD0pilO6FeG@MfhK2HvxriukGSgSSLUQBd4FzYXZDcy@wqU1Ha3FDgHsziZRQfcxg3TQNSdZH9LHrX0pvkbaMXIzZlxPFK3U4lAYknaSyEsqvo8cj@QHFGpAKYoofBl18kv8HjZxngjsLd@dGoMjoCMu7qkqinjpXRstF1CfkMr8nBoGqqpg2BWn5HIkVjT6qTdWAQYzQQKngPCtr4JgGXdByRdJVkAftmwRHfmVMxeAfCKUmOle/AubOaI6GUVPwQ@a6iUgiGpYOcMNVudB2WyvJZx7FQ5EyQ6afoQfD/iTSZAX8DdpwAPaaWEQTwUZQkqEwr2L4SUcIbddBgnG7E1DQ/fY7B3Jkdc6EbJk9vxuxfAySQvTNRHz5T2MO2PYMAyOSo2DDHrzZJu/Bh6/Qm48jieE7Sa14ObCHnCjVVTMHNrZ65tOxy1dkKvjjCYV2TUeEeFBVveON2TqMetkyprbx4GmUYnKPif@QXSQGiBzxx6QVbraY5qyBHmZIDMtSSMeG0dMQkWJbe3XtqtyiMEJkJ2S9PvhShAPQm4jPdTrospC/YPDcZcZFmYnFMUfAwKDhuk3HykSHrzskQsxsgnKctUobgfSKjG5wgugydQvXF0IT9lAxFsJLY6jCOM4ji1vGAtDSt3mjsSTOJHKqxP@lxNPqAtVoqh8cBPiSGpru8J977E0C5@7hmM4vlF4/6LtouYmWslpDl8e6UZr8/hKWjj@0GHN1w4njik1Q6BL3oaijjF8J8Fg6lRkIt@qEaXDbx7p2mGQ4ET6hF4Qi9FVoe8Qc16TJAC1EOTzLOrQobmFfx6KZSOobjpaKwN@KUDaAJhSUlIm6IVXF7y7mYoDJkaEAUDCO9uSCbTaoHzx308LvpD3/FuR@XQL1W0NKRSQ2QpAvkTqr1KMZjc8RNH/Qj0mhAV6AGRFOiyIo0bagKc/RLyU7SrikTR8fE2KXUkj9ej2ZSZS0FFcWMK2sH5lvNQWcilZZlaFAdLLS4vEKozNpw3d27GaNooclja5E57WmRss6LiPJTtXTEJ5ab@ukzPkklf/lphKMHvuAZt1yCIsK4ZsVz1Wk5R/ihTcGnMBi2TJ0orGRa/gDVb7T16feIF5XqUIb9a/qjKJjADqCZD8d5gtGw/9S/6DW2@12/E/ZDH/ZpGMt9zBIPHyf0iB3WGfZvIroWiBJaRqbWJH7m@DIchg3f9blkyQjNFY2CgW2aKYyGk8oFh4kgzTkaAcYXXhJ/D9Ix0nSZFytxISvpf0r2eEWndG/Z58VZhflEHwFIAbeZsqBgH9IROSYZzqelqQznD2UwcDwXOeE791jsJTB@BSSiY5gExgqZKbMEsxG4M7sX43pr7LYoBuEQAy0FOwHeZxPZ9Nn18Q5hkCKv0VJgXRTXCkZRPkUZYxxCfJjcT@7ll/9k7AGBn0C/@HwWt8xiBBJxbRVtKeL9iowyCriQeWBIMpokMUixsAOzUDcBtDFOQ00mT@6jBln@wKJIhtmb4kockTZsfPD2OrsBIqcxcXBSWRALDsXtwCVIZWQX7mfY4Ef2szT48RCXNWcomLYlZNtA@j5SNYFKeEtryrzWRJljKv94xCwvP7bXUgQszzI5M24LtjNq5UIeKCHPr3is1R@CMM6kqCdNPRaiUX@w8Ejq3Ss7ZkZmm0XrpuP80BCYma0Mk@Vii0hbnuDjpGSl8UkxTZJiZGkGPITbV3rWbJ4m4rjcwPFWbkx@QIf7aBbbTelJRfd3i8c@TorXaNGrJho9pAh3DFJa0t/rDWh4434JImHy9qpBEqOBIqMx4UcDVIpMmkqPpxBxn8Q9RY8WUA7rbQHtzP65l6hpIzkV8lQlJYJcIj0xcDs6bYJcGrTR@ALDxPEKVwspveAcuxM6yivmzjHIMCYwQFwVB7lYD8Ua3LizUnxEtwO07QZaCxVREsHTpmnhoIP@a4JRVH6p3JEWD41JrnhWYkhjDQl2FZTrIUjK3xxe640xQZkiBQzxGaTQLZqSTRePb9XPtgXyAQQuTcnS0rfgYmMcsQTYwB8zqTHGNXBclSyZGFHJgdAg0QBjAXYpnW7A21Vc/YVD5ni0bpDDCDYQ/NnGnyVZAsN5rxY0tbHIuDXBLI4kN482R@Q2uUjMUPyO5JdDkZe6tHEFAAFjDOXLRYCAYU0JezwUoNA7JuclEJV9BAXLRRyW8JGiosZ2njPSkagyw4sVI0dhVo5XJozcTCCwsJidJ0YE1iyzs8RQYKKbiYuR4@Xs9sQ5YEGseJ8pDl0heyVJQ91zTEC6V7ngxBKlXhRuQXIwJb5YcRKJmr8p9VXBSC2kU4E@GsN6rphOXSskUhPVLi8niyZKAj0cs9ZEIpDCMRHWUuHn/pFrihnyXNuEGpuMxCpD2mfjvdewy4R9m/eXSGyQU7ZaYyh4pme42n41@IqVRFD2hwOwiwU6MsDY7T/dWmWZqjCRdwVQXDrl7GLzhpBWrBmc6rFZuNNVkfZ0gAK1p@23xcfj3d1E2NfziTI0ugyGK4VCAZn43Ax@r2yrUZUU9vPJ3Pn2VbebH9z8afjxPE@yPwjoSoB1tYMOoEtgUERef9jhmyEQB8iKuXPSkRX3@lfttnkFA55QYudBt3FOGQ1B0AQUaqOXj8ekACKQcoL9ig3E9n0VevTd@LzQlFDUMRSURpPg64w6PQPy4Ic22mfrkyoChoJZWTPBvOWUN7/jDII3m1BnUfhi53tsnpx5F3S7fVd8wouFMVLA3F26wO6uWaDAWfCEkbx7ryKKR@uK4DrsGn7FmMXkdQSnJiZ1z4SKC4@x8Q@DTnU8sDP1LxmYVqDJS9jMJYxP7YpMJ@PIYPGPAMt8CGg/KvelP7CbRKd0Zpjq5QiOnwCj50V35t4nkcUhnZik2Y9zI1Fno@tRsAZoukNrARXLnrqXWnJPdk3czOm42EYaFhiGxAljrjyuBLqa/fPE4vWo3X6cVKRrALhj/5BE5JtQfk4g0hkAjUA5/ICeGEX7X3IwrHdTAUV4gYOXdUzLHSzQwAKW9bRZ/u3GrlQqYn6wtCQqlS14yOVEZasidvDD1pbYgfctfH9WXl5ZKbHM3XG@w8ct9fFObAEM0nAuNS@GO/AKaWX0G0Nrbezi@Xx53i3NN8obm6UoX69soVs/PP39X//97//2H/mKfPkvfNmil/oXncnzvPx88/v8s7sSvtd3zhbmz@vzg7OFTgm57H8pani/Nsr5sfmoNzy3sjwLGF/JjlTtsyn6jCwq1IV/l/7wV5Au6yLbjPJZ@TXim6NIxmabgfE9QD/Kc9jCq0sH0lt5QCILQCeojofeaQZogAfzDVAScEE7UC7PZytKcY/hYHQGfaqSlZF4aM16HaBPSxxJAX1xYcbKhb0o6KEG/JrWvNw8y/LhNxw1JP/mv7yPOlv9sVg8tcViQSy6YjGToZ/i6iv46sznQ/TO5WywHchkXEiJjxbQzFBEIS30aP9Ad@2kyG1Z83RlD0JSYSooM3vBuXr3R84yfOFa1LHm8D5NwSoSOmTCItnv87076JbvkOMuk3C1oYVCQ@5iqDLjREX3Ly6B/IgNAeKaL5kg632oEk/6yCMZn/Lqi@xri24TIsBI1sO3uzTu8QPMRfM9afOc2EvhNUdkPs9fcW4ssTM0oY0pXH@MAB2o8HayQJ6EC9kFi628jVZSM9kL22yfZD62dZgEI2WbzoV@FwYTsDW3Sbj5nvRrkYbcfLwiMqE@XjGqyqRtv4VlFLm86o7CgXRXoNpxQH3Xtd3xSMIeJUAMh2P2r0@PMFIUqEhRqW7hy7ImotXHpvNI6EnXdOhgx@OTI4MI@S82jO3b1Nh28uQlotiBeYCQ0qZ8bT/sRjLqypCI3fGH53g7oN@mC9VGfG5G@jy8QTWFcb@tkfYIMpmcx@MZmpIdDP3Ope@K7H7/eOhPajBtwcpn1PQcaCGGYEIkcPDJqmc1TyHMLZJdQhTRTSHLIby8oDuR16Nx32a0zwl2qRoKMuwKDoIEOxElg9tEX6XoGHP1H@gEE@Up4a1PI6WIJcmLlkYSUsZ0m6FhNjV0LFWDOXb0wMlYjKoemYoXZKErnGgv6eAXJHkXYwTIujPSC1C6Iqy@wvpxduoEPT8xOQ26lnL0z5cEz4s4nukqSrZGstQlqMX4xjvECtaRX5JRIHhuUuGMrDnbnjuN5HVuWXMeoSDf2hY/74tQX0BHF5iRZ4g46YUsLFMzVHwHhidqZPkPENpdvwP4TW78CbLiadZ@/STv1L@c9s4W7dPe7ek3hzCRIlnNsjmRlYfZSmLJsQIzY95NvCqrtEiFGjztJTOc9gT7sBgkAETydv1L/uw2DwidZvFi@dMsEyTRZYhJ/uH68gg@P4VmNolFPmvNOYuO6nz7ddERMLfSL/Yhf3D4F7BQm0pS08M@Z9gGUOSn@9sVu5xE@bXlwovl4gvYCXWCcW4YXOF8m4uuzoMxLCUi3M7C1HP6LcENCULcjSO/BB/H0E6@1oR9TyLppCRFqBzmVI@l2QrKeMwTkB@oTOFS0cXF0Xl8PHzEDb8rgOVUXooFxaaDBvfZOH9G/Uusx49QrqW9Q5gj0cqAbURIhZpDyOrylfs41FHDZYH8nDyxjbFbCQh0bz5rzBa9fi8nF2uOt1DCRTR6zXTXCmuF9BidGqKJETovF1MLT0Rx8/XLv/3nwW/ZUXZzOf9pCL@j7G/Z1bUsP8IDvD1Xb9fZzewGZlu9y07ysAeGx5d/@28ov/kngIMpkw34s7miYK1Ospu5MhW5zW6uwkNxeRnq/Z@//hXaMM87NryLdb7hCkKspCiy7feIdyFd1LCVvC1diMUKOWYhDLYwhL05vKBh1Hh5rUBquqy0qrgOZOQrZY8ip3gyzBqRqRBrMpQ9BayMuEAZK8gxSGVC0RaG7YYy20DmjdEUX596qxHsAL5Kcw5dpTbdeBqhydA8b4ugA22uEfbz/LBZeJ3R5h3rGWVTUlJLSNzaSVm79rz0fw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/4giz5)

Befunge-109 is a modification of [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98) supported by [cfunge interpreter](https://github.com/VorpalBlade/cfunge) with `-s 109` option.
I learned about it from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107944/output-a-program-that-outputs-a-program-that-outputs-ppcg/108195#108195).

In Befunge-109 `k` executes the next instruction n times instead of n+1, where n is TOS and n > 0.
So if TOS is nonzero then after `1k!` it will be 0 in 109 and 1 in 98.

cfunge 98/109 code:

```
<  @,,,"285"  _!k1  "923"3k,# @#
```

Answer (score 3):

## 332. [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) -s, 14908 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@     <!--    (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####&:#######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//      n&goto e 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S     10  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnn M n M M M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$"*0;exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
:e
echo 330
exit




































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Pr"93"s>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85".c"F ._#gi[s]pogr3461!\0k:4op>astdequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05在ｕ92
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwIf4EKlSqaRb6ltVqpZUt25fisUCSZDEFQiwAFIiS1JFd89ur9v2zHp62o522@Pb7hnPttcTMd6JnXV7x56JsPfjhGM@@QeUHxsbjg33P@g95yQAghJJVfkRsbGxkAjk82TmyZMnz8lnS/f6P/tZDB/2zLGmPcsZsZHhjVjHNc8NV2YPpuy@bnp5LSsIGGrH7Y0Hhj3yykKMqYx5I90dMUu3e2O9Z7AYuGpsZu@a1shw08wzDNYyLOcC/LOM2cYFO7DbZgcgsZFzZtjmG8MFvxxjDw3ranA1Ym1nMNDtjseGrmmPyDfP2DMdLN1x@4zpLW/k6u2R6djgVWDsuW3pg1ZHZxR86Bo80iYDUO0zijPvU2TsieN6BqTgtA3Pc9CxBI66azqPd55@fCO8mmEf65CpoWVMbiSvquyFabidmzE09unJ/v5N1yz7RHJstn87S2qO7YxHzsHoJvw82@kZts40uSRrNz0LgMyRYRUzxcycF/jtmy7Upu7XWnlWM/Z40DJcQL5fhRfmqC9DhBOHI5w5tjVlxgSAQR67EMwYMRNri@UzGQwJ/8dG27E7M/DgZAAcgGsMhqMpk5jt@DQAXo7LvKHeNqSOYZkDc2R0mGVC7pyunxuPQYWzM2N64bhQ8RInRcqINzTaZtfEKH4JPAGJ7aHRGveYMx4Nx5A9j3VMT29ZEKw1ZR2jq4@tUZq1wA@QR@4XfcP2s2TaPSzHi5kLQrChCfDcr6uAG9OyGGTnDLODSXtsCz0u0B2DtgzKpdFBUHszdAEk3fKC0s8nPJcMxnvmOj1XHwChdgzCwacHz5jXdlywwQ/D8lawCkxbH7GtLRbfe/owzmohGmW3JYQorbJLxlgs8GTnujU2PDbQp5C2PYLGxRyqvyCGAMFZfC1eZvFslmkZlsuxHDS2ItPyGQZNogQGaLVaVoVfgWlFllOB7vPxNKbTdfWeaRkcSs@xughoEylWyzMN3pkcy6rFeJqHaFM6myxbZIVNtplnm/AusZIGCSHUHFNLefgV4AdQSpALFX7ZHE8tJA0kKSgG22VdfWBaUw59OETwbZZX2SZAhKyqAFkrAoSShhDmnyi8UR@Q29fPAaRkmWfIMoyQa2CNKfBRNjYUYlvIH3mSXt@wLEwVkAVoyhfZJqRagILnIGXApVbUgsL3@lR8ytdmBn6Qx00ocRFQnAFsZRBdm/ADO7AiDXiOBgxGA56hqeCugTmLUCFcAfwKUF@FXABd6xBugcNCXBWRiUxFRRxANKgEloWqKLAcVHEWqzifZZBPyMBmgQFfKaqsmGPFTQboKmUYoF6FzGD9q8DPVMiEisCgWlWoVxUyogLBqABUzeaZEMGrmkV/iJuFuIACNQdxcmCGelEL@IN4UPEqJKlCmppWmpEX5E3LQyHzWaI7rQCVtwl@gCwN8qoBtWiQW60I/hi3CIgrIlluBojQrWFfR1xADSAxA6kBQvKQJ4IN4cGsbWY5SVHoljEy2zx2iyi4gEReQFRC1AwWEb45xChkJwNgkMChCBrUdhbbgnAtQLPkXWiUZQXsB1kIsCOmM@yBgXpnpJcIWWgSONo8txt7hgUkCEyorYMZaR7YBbKeAI45kpFRQz9nOOfYExP/mEvGIx7TcrEbBobXMVyXYVjorb00cSNv3PKM12PsrGf56gJ7M4Azd3XTCjNA7U4fUUcC37gH6U3ns911nQE1zgFyG8txhkv4NvC2CwT0yLkwZlmfsT59OLSgQwB3AxAx1i3IzIVOAgXJG9FUeYYgEsZr900ASEkBYzZdo02494sOsbPAwuezWGZa7V4WoTyI9CtZNnSAK3sYxx5bVhn6S6PNsjWlY5wr6ML7nvk@B/MQ9EbQofogWjoIA9QbYy5CSPc0mfq5k6BmPWcwXzTOmw7CovdN7EOsC30KtdcFtmRM9AGILAzlAht6/gFQDK9BrAmP91wHrOPY8VEI5cKF/hkKHZYEQFqEk5E5MECgcyAK1niOMo2ckXLWmgIpE7ZyMslzPCc3ECULNxHFHXIRB95YoGfsjNuINUzbtImCoEfxULhxDb3D3YSRy05Pdfi50PUNfVFWRgMGPMasRSQt6DcNwL4vVLQJIso6hu2B3OTJzEQBEyi/53SB2KizB6EFos5gtwkJiILQaSK3ZYFQjgQ0OLOYydrDIQN3kHSAPPczReitnS9M9gY8rb7HrPbYdadsMoSaMAcQatR2ul2g3jfGsA8g2KDD2tM2NE@oZKQeoeMQJ2oP54s5s60bEMY2oNi7z77OegagHfr2LuSUSH5WgOGQikCo0G3e79s6YAqL0B5OCS0AJozRdRwZ3TuO4RGxgFwUNn1MzDN61DSgnXVnzGiAcgxQKcgWNtAucB6/eSF8TFBYWBhMyqeCjw0bmk4bqBIaPVQf1ukO64IWEenyUUzU221jOPLpxCF2ZtoR0ehwH0UjcpV8YLLXF9bvg1Q3TzUQNKSciBygnxGXRZWBJDYdea2vqoBkYBuhMMw4Z7Gmt5KHEOc3UhdfYZi5HLwSl@RhSE0C5URiEuMRshLkjma7j7xwhNyGZBVobe74dvHBLZq8O2BSN0wbc6MC2xFkJXTCfCyHIcHPug1IHloIqzbngEHnHO4ArXuDBZCdMJNWJ@oqK7oMTPEuoAPHdhZABWSGcDHIvA/VBRHjMXIN3QqJkZqLN1dHyLBnWjR2ZNCHDoeOCy2DM50psjReZRHqcrjGkwj7iiRo4PNdK3QZcezwRyOuvQ0t0KioiWFLBalUB04BTIzrEsDzHJ5iJMPU6gmWn78LYv2cmKAvtW0DBVvdnXIgUDzoniGhKTNdF9jgOXYSvA8KOhOZ6BT6BL3TQc6K6KB2fzNxGSl6d9wyJzcVljY6yl94wrnusi7qKi4IHdCIEvGuF09WyJ1iRrxExRmOFIrK3yIEpEAyVHmiC@oPdBL7wGiOp3Y7Ic41MTHNxPGoWxSTYMCIXEZjX9WHo5u5@wLckGgGZ9CuyVZhPei@JQneErpRTtBDkdFDd0HOgEYIsnqp1Gnp7Aq4h8ukyS7FRuGSvqqcC9My7E6Ylo8IzEu0vDJPwnPbZJAivRqWAINTyamTmEPge2KCIorgoCh@34oOJO1xP5JruOPYpoEGluCiSJJdhoI@dAAJyowJwofZNkdNX1y5dy8QXNaqVSA2kKaAbXaSURUhGJGRgVNDYJmkET8ReeQcj7BtJJJQXgx8zXMDYhNQarXGLkd9F1oc2a8FCARoFWyk5ACxfj0/Nc/GnZsVbaMjBhKx1YHQZLZHYkWAzp@3huoqrMbnsAoqRByxisSL8Qn0LeIlV6xQ0Q/mGh6Kv1U/K5EaTmAOfFpdiCIe1XebEfTutG35IgE3QWPn3KgF2T/zdf6QEaV9mSBotLdaKgeCzYHDYc92Th5V/bbIPZWWaZfnHCynrVvkvI7BxSDu44MHRztHX28ugGGZrfJNB8XMFQvY1Y4nUs8eKzlZK69HYcwAP2yuho0R58OIgu/NJGcSEZWmbehcJgE6D48@uYkSkIQQHZQCmPF3Q6ThYUDoElq617/RCbNeKgVJhlGCsEw6YAHM0IBZR389yM@z8Zs3WHk3MzX03TFn1ljnAAJH5cAO4snoeUMAC7xaXd4jUlyQQk0bR1JnpmjIID8fo9R8MzMkSkdI5uPD/b2jKoHt696ZYVkSBVG8EchSutuRgeatcccQFoUB9gemNkvJs4yjPE15XYjgdnsOwbO6ZUvgAwDUdWSHSdYgKJrXh7zv3iwbuUrtkALIThBuypVReaj9oRmN5AO7uDaqvIt6UfKYdVah08IeK/Sd77ba@byxmStFu632LM1OFOiAhGLTCeRGF7zOPAld5JkU6YvVfvaPH9/KuEdCJKgCUpAzz2IypeVZAmovksninrILGppjGfIL4ngiE5OKEg@GUOW2R8pnJPzexBwlMkn@VZMQFlLf2TnQHgaB/eE@GskgpQF1ceyZ3C5OWbQ9oBHbsZyewzYgDpcOgwRBbFpazJ2eY9@qIR0dsagxnAMB/osDN/oQ@hrzDSmOFCuqrvL5E932LoBLq4UsIokwRKAUCi9/oZ/rgK5ZuY8PPt@DTkTNZzKhOUMPoCASh9CFpnbElRyYBAnJfn4WFjCcD7nV2gMPKTIhgYX2GV0YcWfmvdCROKasLAy/MEtfdW5h/AtneoO0wIWTFhgiKDt4@uzxwdO9JzufnY60fH7OnsuUCoA4SK8FspDc53jD1rrBmyYWC8HFoG242LyAC4xBQQkG1seeC4xbxiAyz8ASquEzSYmvOn077iVvFuYCfaUv7DYnoSfY@HhQPyIo2h0LlRGXT8Bhf4700x@Nhl5ZUaCV98ctGZRW5Yu2Y@k9heJBx2BZioqqy8Ehjmt4i2JAZrypwWPwwS0QHaY0gqhbAweUF5rUQ9bAEhw8jVpZZq8PujDO/BluUg4pmEqjdEBDAF1ZCctGDJhsgFv/G9STyEn7K6pW5HStZrScIgbB5po/hF3rGqA6JaC3AlQkb1jZ6b3Te2wKXBoh3QQSY/KGP/mDfYHFQJCkUVPU8wPkELfA8VLkFYSj12MczQUupeQzuU21kFdALQM1DWRWCcfcpIE@avelkSMBPMnp0rhBhAq7Xlu3u/KGbwgyC3LfR1DUbP3l6andAAH99B7lDafU6tNGXW0kK@x2lA0/fLIC1DtXPKTdwAFol4xAmvRlS/hZR7/Nzjo6ta4OU0aDod/nSEP2ZAcEqTcO8OuOEW17GEGJeiobc2EVDPxWWTAgZGFUAV@IKQUaFPS0QHoK5ksCoRfFQ6Ac4FuRCGw2msHLwSeyI3wElW6ke9OJezTij3INjpZ6Q0AiDTa3kUt7OD44gt4xpHzk0lC5yKTZhRHHcXTd46OVEMmfvgzig64WQqBR@XBE2g6nbYEIKBap58A5gK5w2LQ/G2VEpR8oDRKkPOHgA0gQNs0e9IDPQGRekB1eEJ4SucwX6cx2LmyE1jJYUWqZIz7Y74xdnBY0O9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK/T/GHLaPNRVh6ZSgFKoM4GxsDBoQSQrogVGFQEnc89oi7o4Yg1NKuMhNMvAF9i93eBi7UNPl4kDVCJApLaY/GRq@xInyu69AaoeYVshYXfiU6FU6WfBAigkchwLpxGSfwRUJJOnAEFekHjLej5IBB3heF01IcSA4WJetUZGvZNnY9rhIlkhWZs43Fg@KaduIyvra3Fy/FaPA2mbTBtoWkbTSkwbZNJIhOGk9FEMdJkQt86xUC3Rvy6HkCeJBtIAxOUHN6Yw4ReL5ezjbReV/2vht8kVAVgHkJL@AE48WS1isZkUqxd4JwNyO@Rsu8i7Ry3XXPoo@CrIBBwu4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jgrrpaowMqi4ojQaKmAk3flrPnDZOL087qdPreBpjJyt6FfRDYF6jxEDuuc54CIJbPVeWgLcl69lyo9KqxjPxjUSiKFmQkJ5MflRMpnSO60TcAJpKnJ7GAaU@durtvkvwJmktmQwRBfnomqBlWFYiLl8WIf1WspFMxSFuMp4GtlyNxwEvbUSCR4XGEQFORPvmBFAJDRO6uOicAjFImpzC5vq5MexP3WiAcNQNpGwcQZ9N60NjIC4e5ZJvePyoQDen6QdyLw8Hwi0O3qG8NJxy7i7wnJ4qc0tMgn73XOoOnJGufCqD0iRHusv4WlyRJOgJyYdDomI/MT1swrptOGMvOtK4cAAUUwfXk/4YmGWw/iYNVGUOBaPdd1h8/T5AZ@F8D3YlOHUl8QmwAECnLcMPmShKJThZAtIFLUwxgS/iohU@KqNSJjjrCcbm84XhazlMrUJxWAYTMnu24xoSoARiCLSMhBYdCTXmr005oJGvW/MSvi91aah4mwZwxH3L0Qm3nF1H5oOGg0h80M8hypHRESzgH11gjzKvC9foKBsCzdI6bh96CCgNcmItrK2B76E43rAjjyYQVUhghxv15NodCJ0XrKNpWqGd75YDP6QKQHYfKgm1UhtU3MBLUsEz6VfyHh8WCnT0p4cP9/jYCXW22L3iOFpz4HTGIFf6etORYffSbA/oybSdgQloCOK/ObOOHGfEtXywLBuZ4UqzORhbOo353ByWWRmv7bQci4aCVkWdhR@7nm7pfBAq8N359AnI@s9PjqtyORJI0c8HK9PGccjFyXJ8HkTnHGm@NZge8jhhiut5EfutYFkbshnfo4AeY39RG9RR4L6J7kGTwjkU372I7gNc0Aaysj@KQNbQ0Q9YooC4yA3XBvmOl2rmGt2X6mBhOJXCccFxlttLVSP381G3O@ecJeczCVmTNXPOkTNf7DanI0azlOeBcOXbXJgooAKFCRfA3QznM69wrUHfsIIZxCMQTHCWDPp2C8Un0E1QEuer0AwQpIc4GUIcGqfYWBtkTe/WsAW0qaHEQwuxNWon0IcpKLkI6wrzh7gr1FJsx5@a9Dj3dEC1p9GTrRqfzEbVyeVam8IH39ebAGKrVgnWJC0LhinF42Ewgkp5gxhUTJq/v1XUcDWGR2PqAkWpCJ4CWsNEy0ink829huIRErpMPD2dfJTRPgPlA1ePrd9TekYFk1uKLbLzceh2H9gGS03mUQb1MLa7jtWR@KQX1D/j6hJWhL/mIFy/RgwfXEw3WLpm4moWf4khsMvIqrdbcG9UXe12gMg6uRAQtIZLdnWWPr9idejBzmVvaJmjBruWR06zj4UfjV375oo6LlK6rj71BH/JSpXtHH38aT3T4BCEgY4TWUVeW5NgQSbIwSD34LpXMOHCm5E5oo6dFhaYWF5VhkxNaM4Dsg8weAIVFibklwizfmVczcrSNUDxTBiYc286SDMjeS13LX00MmxOW3w2cTm6@bSPn0yVkt/25xDKLEMTLSBomugHWayw45OHe0dHMlCol4jv4YRMGZqd3u6DvLGs0AEmo4Uvs486cfYRxkmiFi5AkwJlounHB@KtAHGDOgGpIyvoGW4CHJM4l9IGZ5q@oohc4PIRhMun2iPCUQgsYSShTASsvDD/z22uOfn5LLM4SxEmAd2Je2XArZmUx7b5Wvag3yAxFILEue5Ji22r6wliX@tqkujHNQc4FwwqE0mBUIZ6na0Bd6PQIqu@ZS/rGanUSK2zRqPCZ/ghIsr0tHjXXwiq@/jk02HEIP08H/haWffGcuAgBRq5xVg8fyrQrODTLWTWHbemt1upuK6JyTCz0htw4J7izUwuWK7KsxiscSIWQkui5pc2zS@cihTrOSnZN5aZQ3GCDITlwWnIBC8lW6syNZkMcsYBvdBdVJ3L7JnjeWbLonWwXcvkS8LCzrrsI8aHFGAmmlwFGwbhDdsztDOsjNniZ76k2McE@VNHA5oUlowcEkl2icgkVGqIRXZ1hQ4iW9cYkYGIa485fq8DnRb442MHMvvYX0sdlTmIafjLU5B1nApioLzNz/@iD1cMlPMbMq90LkbjcZnTtM8cmkUKTc2MrOZRzgxjD86s2zG7pten11zQMA88rLYsd96g1aXXggA0meJP05MDDdP7EjZUp64c0YdG7BekPL80ZS7ZltEd2z2a00Qzk17fEVIqFSlwt9UylwUFJOBqs@C7IBjwSmx5mpyT1aD14AAPdIvAP7lONCv6zVVNbA7v0EmNIJb//a/f6AD@b9dOH/orHM8MDU2QFLCmpO7SyvKjooVeiyuWD7uPLVMnxJDpLpBt3YUi6VZoWAyapvYlCeSNAU5U@DUOtIkvkEVXkBnPOZ9nDL6LE1k0VWcD324vC3tjlRdPiiaVQF3sEBK4zGUaFImYLK8EY8IndiKKOzLcuzMVLMViRMy83vvj0Zi/QRy@sxLNIf5WtU0/ZCavt1QDFFK9ZRorqtzVz8YdRxqe9UKxuLAg7Kz0NLMsgVTiTzI30bi4@LyArtmD7j74Lgs261@VC/rcRRWePfaGUot0@w63UUMYrEjBtfh7WRDT3/MUGpZjzbTo9Z6U6EMHQvHXWCi4glWKIM28gWZLb01RFOp/OJWF6xWA41TbqVQmu2TCejhcHh/1U4pfKi2OPZHbHB@LRh4UvkpW4mNzVGB/3ewdtQrdlTnQLUnrRIxLmfmi5Q63goYzpRTHOMd5ovOFNTfDPnZI7bGluzPTChKf5SOYnFg2zu13G8/MtgPiwJCpm7KqBV1HpMMglhksuJslhIuU6RVZVGEuQmMHtFDsxKXQtJgFOO0RLkRdQlPvwdD4AlBcZhshEtlZhqm2c4G/peJDHzRh/l7co71ZmKv3YE6S1bZ06MeXdgdzQ444pHkHoV6YnkGvxYg9W5jRUdta6D7fBILBxOjg4F1k7ZmW47Fjeq9CUM8FLPD3YoKO4tLUbYmG2KPmFTwoWDkxq1Dd6jlWodhTdHgtrfWx20W@73/fl8OFHEpV7@BQgfjj2Kr/XcrXzxT37K4Koi1kLq6ajRhXdLGL2JQ/o7O8dKAY4HTg4pLtZ4oUU1b4AOKShHEi50KfBt@/Q9exDLVB1zGckjgN0h1GKBXBMHK5iP13SS23OrXO@zGlW2A37ypEpHLPLAM6K3rfqlKmZdQPjKFmMu/PorrW2BgbCxWNw9YXBu5GXqFkvH@mMn4x1v3xf5xywA0vYag3vmb4XrnGfhptK5mJDiq7cbcoM8/UhiB9D1F1fgaGZ2i4HaNnj4dztTqnndlHq1HWHwZN2unM5Q59PpQPFe@QlObkc8@g30qNiWt4uOysmstkMr4AE5nHmbOs0qSyYdwvTP6eS5hcZinPwuLcnRsxLk6D0BJd2LiUBWnLFHsKXCoptmkboym@35ObthzH@pCaAqbaMVEUA8mSFvCuqrFb4o6/NYXNhi48HPBodZcNWvDextctAT@oNK@q9OhE03vVpoRTqQOc5pq3rh6@iUxb3ZUK7grHMSG@pNdaLkv6oyGqXJQ3V7Y6LqE6LcPS@WdSyK2CV5KzK@HNMw1/ChinjPlE8WyCP3aDKQ2ngCyzA1pK3xgYZF0h5eudL8Ze8FkaaOLgb5n3xDDaymTPaC8LMDSBL9j4npuZjghLI8cG/WqEqwdRT7FwfarvuowDB3OJC5F8MNB7Bj/qYhWnnA1Y4BodrtbNjIuHLsp8XU4bos2Gl5eTBDSqM2PqBd@FAJ9M21Cv48Hdw203Gn8bx0Dfo7UvWxh7u4u1@07f7ht9vho9tC1rHECPI340yaqsQ657fVwgNxzOLZyP4tNyLOt98ImskTNKx@kuzNMebqnF/WAfBHeqt8DD/9w5eKePOO9Aw9JW0zfG0C95zsgZGhLZlgW1cKCHv5fx0GDq@@86grRSzweMBN@/K/w7dcue7oyGQ/o0h9bYoxdFlWgn9F1yU5cveKGllo7bk984g5bsO8r@ahiacV/MYlrmqN3Hreicso2e02r3zbsy3TL0kW2eKcGQD7e@l@6KmDGZ9BCdZcsE9LpTGemlGvU/xs/Bskr3R494txYaVsgri0boaLO3NNTP2h4fDUUTK@OAcKQ18i3hZdpUX349NkczoJEVUuHwLp@WQMOyvPtrMpZKVrTzYsaG/bUaS6mUhHQUyCUjAwKPuizZ@dVzkSaWzfLXsgxFS0k5iqx2@RB0@yuKaHTQjIzbgvscfc0thVrYydn9cc@7zTD5cH0HRDR8LR@2oBXSkSFr6LN02/8sQ7NmKbh1Er5NkLnGxso5lfzKSRUKp1qS7pjwacIHqm68dAzNMocefzOpu3Qqzl8hBbr4zflCjpvpYmXar5iO0eVTIGi6S0QcODRJCzKI1MYJfRxBR2bOBS/OuGynB0xdstgscBB2mdiycPHR4uoP@0zps6dGT8cV3I/NES4BXUAVRLKLFi3dCftrY90zvzaGki0jNjwHgk9DutEDA9C2AN4TvWe2H81VRJhJH8H@@lH@mSN/dLpdFxd908MFVKFhxcAUkhwnYqS6JugNC0LeHLcPj8CYNSC@uXJh6EVj685winvQpmRaNaxujmiU1f8uUx2XLS1bmYmL8WA49vzP4jzQEq3oKPTgjNy9CxOAS6@BtbK@bo0Wj1RHhlxBCvM7xZlxmTT@uWk5PfZ5McNAaAMhDIXzBYTzALrnZ7guyLUXUCKl/Z7TnjjQIbm8YK@hbo0sk0zbHK0ezRmNcI1Q8MXC8J4D9z0oj/Et3/9QCNLJYow8vlvWn214vqN/B8o7dsZu20BjeIpJVC3wUzV2gzXNuE/EwVNYLqJaWtuxoHmBwVrYZNqOPR5J7the2SsUVvYKZTYpFiJkwBJf23vyPBmlBloDfpcUaoDyN/as6cy0dMHADSIzbRDElvPR@dCBLvGQn750RAuQ74izg0dEtYldP3QW6TvPpq4xem@FCZj/ePDQaOO04Z1pP3WeOLYDvdEQGOXgyOAnCcwt9FgcEaM9xr3ygJ/OnckcE9glnRCXNvSh0YL6tWam9@mLOOCH@khf0hXR2CDpf6HpTloxrZbhfkGDfhHzMpV2PkOPjAnpFssJhrdBadRuc5EYx@Pm2sjcjI03dBybv4nbZuCjPlnNVaAroNf7T5TLuLx/blxgoX42X9TDc75KxOjwoy6WldU1Wo7F3yvWJNkmXxOgu6bhKY/x5ARyK@SYBNKXt5KHbK7kITPVCCTZc92jSfrFqsYMpDr5gCVAfd1tOzgT5htWrM6JHHdwB5sOdwzwhQMtQPwEOJbeHvvHN96VLWvQGtBrqcIQqc0jo4V7jVp0RshIn9yuTD4y5B@QEFnRFR4rELArbNQFlngG2kjy7m5rTo@ax6o5pBdx6qXT5bRYR7JNo/1Gx1Ezh/A1G5ue84cyK0/JuGSsOtKMaBRZ0Wn//MKWNL90DQQay5BGfRd0fmW0ang7OLxlwXzIeGDgJPP8LMxS0dXx@lRYZ/F8eshcXUPyTxAEXhKeJsjlQ2lnqeSJ4OH/8MFXFeiEm4VccKAJsK67Z/Ah82PX9j/vQ4HPHG/UNSeHkG/cdLCMnWCx8hAFPrxloGljWSGg9uyxxUcfepF1V4MOqWMSHYMrSRax65EhGfa5RMfLTW6XyOFbyZQdPE91ZHQk/3QFnGmQHge7ysJg/nfBBGqUN@JiT1XhiJ0Ucv7yz0XIvQg4A8hbzkgaevRVht6zg8eHJ/LQUxf2Tzt93IxxS46bO65BK2YiQ1Jf6G5kvpMvR@uY3kh5cKxKu48PZAywBN98RkOCD87MzX2Wjnv6p5fqir5UC0JfY7RYQHx08uRxarbxkyV2@64zMJJR793j4zRubPnq8ULvaOx9aB1dZ7I0@sGeqiYXkO9zm2YHl3HPBSktg3RigDYKxPiIn/Zyp3DVdoZG52Q6ND6FzhM5uPeeyReWFvKpfm72sBWy0lJEUUNlJbmQS0ZWZoOybbjhd1l9nplD5JZt@ij8s3Q5CkoOWcXNLpYeVs3435RiWMZfifBhkdTMbWodmRK0jF4fTYru/X0zpqrqMjwf612oV5ZfWlnzARbND1vO@XtMJRu@8iKFTtIIqEoy71xHvikNgHUr@MLhed8RjK2ly2BWAQidCwsb/IVhT3VbormsVeJFGWLjoraVQT433mNCKlzhc45nSi@c4wuX1LNEm4zJOxI@cSNRdncfHNwV4cjH5epQHz99zp7pHh5tsjpgNMfGe@R4Jhl9IeG4FZ6rt3Q6teMCKG0lvN5wcXsus2Pd7Tj2dHL3JBztbMWunY4sDmGhjQIZljkxF/VVbT6u9WzxMqO70uabOJzpnBwcPfLGB/Tu2/9CVTMZOtAIv2qGW@@omaCBswSa9Cmekhf1OjkIWUMb5RYZHJILtdHHxgSXo/DR4EVK/cL@rbCi79tMLu9OVvkVV/jlVqR3yw8dWVbOqCsA5lf4sbwcej92rIu@I@/qruEtWH@8MEOrClJaUZBShDu/KWZwEJQmFn3zchEfty74n4XUemKM3Nyw77TM3MIy7HTx6Er2BI9gv@3vL6fQXVre0nP8LR/cvji9i7GxMKEn@pvFHsRpzhZ6ARM0@mPaEnHbe36CtAUyr2H3TH5qI3vgjPbItjCTzxxcsb4wyYfm8OF4uDyjwBLxwoCbXHwu4AtQlZ0Ljz2gLXQ4HT0T0Rfo/bg27rY73xl3NLajZzV7af@0Db6hlW8x9OTgQO1Ewk6lksn5mx@iGyr5VkI80Y/vAoSwV1dszd/sBx7h/kd/iyEe/AXKh4EbcwUCgTs/E3a1quZLbBvvXyiDaJGkFNGJjlcK0qqz9Ut/5165rF7j7kWxLDJ/Z2V4Wio/8RPg4lmFUCYmnalsfQQ@68G@P0aH17MrRuoKyEdqPgM2WYluxK74GyIhS@uXzw6e7R2f7Jw8P65nGtdi0t/2y/Nm25BasCH8o2xHhLL7aAM2yM//pY3DFiRHB@ujmuMF5WJQshtFq84VbVYocRvjrF/atqLQ/ldFuob8SSJPjXxBpkEnDjsoMdWPv325zLeNWoRScZ2DFilNqLMyyyxKeKhDk163ff@b94KQL8tm0Zcn7B/ZCgTdc5yOn6JnsLufIMX9nYPHz4/2WJDBGdFcmJ1Rv1rK8xN9UVSQDKinrkmraaos7keJQ11Vq/H9OCAmLsdZmXYd02m6QOcQLMAO7lf2Y2@wxDrBBwzGw0pR/us3lOu4jAtDkxA2HmQqznzMYwB2gjsJ//THHX7afHB@SHABjjugfpHOaRD8XcJL9ggjRqlhDpdfg0Onu9N24PBY@dnVQgLdOgBUeUFHf904FipJJ7XwO438U7uChIhAghOqcYQRT@ByPXZu4l5gnocuHog1T8q4KIEOgZPZDt7xAzTPdLr6ALI@tkf80Bn/iIoY0JEcMpQ0W6fM8osSxEjA@NYakHLLAMbLPBvUNmNUZl8AneEoXplvSJekWvxWlAA0v9xJ6o8GViTgrRO0POXUVd79yj9TehUG5hGYv@ObJ5kHYPsl39YF8y9z80sF6/32iVuzvEQzhKfk@SXgGQnxj7iPXG1k80MAZojDg8ECrsnMAVTTOWEdg/MU@FsCZjuDk6h/CpUG5AY15m/@5@kZbiOBx/SVFQVJCoUBmdY8GxO@AOnGcX2FfCGnKpBJ6TwASOdr93BnJQeYTJahEQjn5rD6Cjqfra0tJqJGYFQLFV6zyrr9Miu@CjO6DmGFiz5mrs4gDkSZxQC/mh8NupaUmsSoyJviahzZUseBPof8sW9Cu@0jQmQJQBbHkYEHNk/wjquROw2OnWzhvVGRuxfWfUCSCj0OmZKi4O9Xf@qMgHzmdurz/eq4AI/3b3iem8fvcKPTHpEe5dsta7bNMrjkwW9rMvIADiqbudlVRutWfIEgjhFEWVxEvvWX7HR0ajcUTpsMyPSHC4jZBvMvKr0lNMvLvXP7rL/EzZP6EFns/rHtoOqzD4VhCU3RsopaSM6KlMstLJJfIj8ZKA6eQHIFyQGbApbRNswvnKG3s7t38NXDZ8e3zrOjkPGbwYCr17ZSp5KcrjdCQzxarPkqebCvHD95sB9UxCzThQg3BknGL4m6qiSzEQ0EOVshf7Noi3J4s3TLc/yC76G9md@stiprFOlWPtTMB6RLq1SlfdprcjNxrbgIW/n8qizN4CkR0Lt8o@CtrCaSl9f1xlbt1I7Fb1PCgobwMiZvYCMA06m3sa4gsd8uHBYsvGvxBC958qJtMbu4LYrrWTxWCfcpj5yz2YFSvkPEI1LeIBlgkYKsBEGXtr5DLoHPjj3T@F2Q/ACm6LEzkQwXMqswHgF1ElwriVxkdmijf15hX/f6ltkSguN@@LmFwfFq4ZGF/KieRFLwj/7nCSf8iyYn5YlMS1ISSeR2BCvNVh2BGMBLCtCgUXZ7Nga95pkz5EdB09TjQyMwHTnAfkGjojUMBvvqeADhuvQ5MmgYGDi3BJEBk/Ewq1yWAi7hn4A4SeEZk5BeHc9B9AsuDzr5xCQp941Jx@wBb08k08DRPlLVBgtPScRC06mIdlykOpvVwsqm@DFu/4yi/YOOypzMMqDXdRn0QWOSiF/Ek@UGpI/u8YsX5/GkuIiW6MhO/wzLzs2zO8Psb6qrOYk@8ltncDDmIm5RKt3mEuB2EzA/dCq4h6ZUkvueQPeKVVEuPx65j8EIYkSiO9CHLDG2@cFcMiNr4jRhp@kkI6nGz/azWSpF6hJ8yENmFLNLJt5/J3R7yhJKFYgAXT27g5835pDVVVlugJkSSbJ1vB9qFyQuPOQmKYCGC1HKBLaKJARKBOSINxKZEzjEQX8Bzx5y6XizBd50XQ6NljmIEyo1q91jkfu@5iVHsVQq@xU6zxVLDKjvNjuUFQB7i88Fcj1g1z9EA3AGyq0sxGaM/DbHi1G6MZ6RR/7pG5CdWOQ8zuBQDgawZqdltvsu/hJ7NrQVPEeo/Pxkv1lMKiILT/HouWYHR3P5kdKhAudfAgLNVJkLGq9wfe1jjIbHszX5MSF4etg@NRjxBkuNRdFw8/rcGW2q6kqq9yP6tQAhc9gB@LudmgE4PIcwmFdf4LeY2f/sZ3hBr5hYV9WzpnueiuczFXiplTzLs4/WTyVpvZ6p3l/XQYsavZ6cikxXchsPz41@t3XQU05FkWVZTlE24vsbz0yt8PL15DqrFl@fDdVCXX49aYjFavqsMWHPnn32tvk2KU7Op@JpgjRLtnt4Jao5VFxj5RK73C5kY2cl9AieN/yjLXtuauxiXGSx01O8eFfcFBWlHm/AP3m9gocHqtfkmrzdePs2WWe6PppM2WkML7Nkh/fJnxQlHHXStOSxaZoKOx16nQ78nD5r8BuZY/xJpRIS8x2kOnerDCZdcpvsGL3eeE@fcnczNsbP/siP@@TzFy9eoOEFPezNUcyHTbHvlf1w5aaejzEto/3pT9au05fPmlt/@s2BYqzh5xA/37l@guZjNf/R2tpHDx7kcmlADTc/@/zZ13d2dnIP0/ln9fx2Tsqsbf3JH6@tadqWpqw1PE9txOtnZ5@JWiYnyn/6o3jz2bOveV4t@398421NxdcmvM7ZJvAJeLJMBSO@i/BTUcY6Y2/gOesy/Cfzm07ErKO51X3DYm9iQOVqbEp/zVklrzG1tr353753@Do2itU05YUL31HsdaxQjHEjGMCWDWznsVpsC4MVrmNTpVqtgnHzv/17iF/7KsBBn@kWvGr5AFZhGqtJVYpyFasVwKBqGqT7f33jGxHi4WyiSmJc8NxndXjE3KYmbjfg2aBnS8Cz06SMovBQ9r2eA72ZwdTiPfUe2Ef9keHgx@Qf28BDrKUKaN1H9VQq1ZCbEjzyS9LdVVU7BQbA5kiLWghhybdyFxZ18z14YE46L2JEU0BURFfc7DsQqXGHFzfDvVjwVF78Yz9HQqywdt94WKsBK8zWshu1FD1rp@UyR7/CNoui49wHJpFm8VMxzl6xx37l1MRMURPT6fT9JloniFJpEpshkHEcsdgcZmNsZmNRpxgLorFZmA8Nt4fPn/2vf/b9P/se/X2ffv8Jj5mzO2ZX2YB459B0avyBr1hzxctTskCBM@Viuag0r08TG8CpGkdMzXx8Fc9n48f8ht4MY6fJYLQzFj61Gr7o37eRib433HyfWmihELMoq8MFSI1BF@wvyJPq57WGhIJTVaqrhXxD4vQYlLFWYvX7UE2itlkSGzUtrx1C1akir7j@usecGGiQBYi0Dc8a/NE/PKF1DUeU18htLfChULeftTDdOx@AWVY3tKyS/6iwpwmxel1pGA0QZFktAHJ/rbxWLBfKmtJcAZdVbjsZhvHMi52rarvVar1pt3R4WnpbV0f6fXlTLsra1lif6FN91Bq3Jq1Re9xWVSH2tr7GjngzaLBU8Jym7nyey3LTN5LBwZ8kOZOYEPtHeGqqprINYKQZeIH0QEZQ7vAPysFil/A03m7U324AhdRSW9Q8GzXJzyV85Ob9Rkq6vq6DuVLx/7dqobFCDzdB4RrXqdTWy5ok1V/W6ikA@dIHKXOYcrPW2CKPMC0/Md87nnPiBef@VoNBsqmt@lbV2aUfxIRHagDcrbm83r@fksF0HwDU1kGQSKZS65K0hjy87vMqCNyopYJCYR5AutnaAgK43rquXde3rq@3tuB/i97X/hdcr7du/dNn9iwJM/NvsHpWK0K@arXTulI7VU594muAXVZq6CIrp2CowRfCQWcmxKB5GmUhtsE2YngMVTa2IcRevfvyf8bf6bsvfw97egZ/QkzZQAWhxPUEeDH2xGZP@GPb8A@/wIou6PCkho42f9k4h6Aor2RW5sO0CbVYSMrIC5tOt4lziDJ7BUEZMggmasWC2EypU43FtsTCJrGIn7/1xOPxf/JKK23GuT6N@zBfeZ73JJIzTJs9YfijP4hS0TKqpF7V@LnH/MT5n1/0/JOfX/YIsasS4I4B7/MYx4kQg4qISVJNiNW2BrhaD4e1JdQgzqufSc93JFR59RFNWrS5Olc92KuWSjU@Ir/@jChn4@EGvFX431uDsgjYwQixS3y1XuPf4zf4x07a@Hf0Gv/YyRv8OxrhH3vSwr@T1/i308K/kwH@PXiNf09G@Pe8h3@nP5fNqhVx/ZJQkVJL6vW6uJEhnFRi27XTn@N11Y3/9Lvf/Ga8Wo1LcTr1PqeC@q8mK4BNz4tX7seFWJWtq@tqxsq0M2pLbYHBZBmXZfqZvtoBGbGpsozBMtPMlGUGjtoBkwF/GTCZmS7L9FjGztgQEHzBNGpmRmjqwqcHf10A5MKfiYtJWmqmzSAhCyVJui4LwYPpqnkq1EElFl8ZIObLqpyRC2YDLxmoiw2tVGQy0ojcrL86jTfw9FqtlGOtqbF2@orFPFARKjHl9FThgx1QTMLE9XWzuff0YbOpIP88feIczv4PDwdR68r/waHz5NAZOPB/eHj4BBpfLXU/Bazl/v0qsBr/sx2rVbZPy8SwAqYVU7a2T2tZCc2FFPAhDd1SH/jMIMK3tnYqxC8SKN1doIBXeXFROa@Q@SKwgqFZmQUIgnGD/4XnAnhzIMhdwHN@gQayofHixWlo4gblxcUpajqgwob/IEJHrf8A/@b/u/6fPGdJlqg3konL660EPUn8SyYvry@v/XctmUj4lsQW/KED2DHK5XUNjRToEkz1RLKRvL7mbvBOJLc4wBoks1WjuLNwwD9iYZKULH8l/mG/kLT/nMYrTJ8tQjg9nWQyyUorOFYbJ930K5oLTlbokqT1Vl1t/MmP6PD07SQFyucqFXWDcYuW0yqVXGDbLFYqxcCynkiUbj@1zLZaAHktl0smKxWwbAdgM2ANwRYBbGDJA1TD09s@A7w8OKRjxYFL5GN4bj9nC4kMXT6A99jExbJ4717Cvx93eyd5755WylxdhS7DITipc07NZsd0m010z15diU2R1gSU8mDPFK@u1EwppcaTjpt4ihcgQVIJSWUfaTVKtQR8V8ttJtk/yAPA8ltbhVytVsiBuVDE@cvbD2GDievx2GXQd28mOWuMrytihaui0Lo9fNjldYyqneXyyQQw1yTIf9cx/OPOaqnE3ZMsV0gUUyX/r7qWZDUQRvgf6tvZVG5jc@M@iGn4N1n4IE@uXBpV9bp6aZRx3PK60vavn8R9tMa9e9kSoLWYqZwKzebDnZOdZrMqiiL2qPBCR@LuAt56NXTjdaryfKlRxxI2TuPxcuU@kYdazDOgAz@cFIdughVLhAjB7OImeSi9oPqjGWuCRl98CSV/jAMcY9il818HHtZhLdbDh/WYaZrMZBY9zGLcn97tdhjI4Y/vG1opLj6hixE@QuzZ453dvZO0tiWxmLa/s5vWjp8/iKlozc/s5J1F@9HezsPD5xDh2eO9neO9jw8@3Xv@DNw9djF7Aj7vv2ffqGmB/YK9EL5w3@iGoRtjw2hejMcXr9kXptk0of6sMRTC6bnMM5qQ96E@K0cFfm3T07/4QneH9LB3P/z2ux/@d@9@@7vvfvvb7377@z/98vvfht@P4fdd/v3uvyvl8f3TL//F77z7rd8Gx/8Evz@E309@@uWvf4P/yP5H8PsvEbc/8n@RcPwnAKxf@umX3/vRT7/85R/A71/5vx/c/v3KTxb/vv@t5T@M973fWR3mu/8efr/LYQVhv/tb3A2/t8L/Fg/3yz9492v/gf//if@Hxt9@92t/hC/f8s9/8Cf/5d03/6OmFf/k37771vfefeub7771nXff@qfau1//t2om@vqdd9///b/8g9/9yz/4H@n/x/T@3ff5f/eDf/7n/8uf/29//gf@7yfw@w9g@smf/0doG3/z@z/E/@/9/t/84Q/x/3/613/z@7/6N7/0b8jwG9zwf/@rf8fff/Ur//mvf/M7f/mTb/z1r/7kr3/j9//yf//l//PX//Nf/fe/91f/7Jvo@Bs/@cs//KW/@Oa3/@Jb//Ivvvnlkve3V76/fA/3L/8RXN4/n@8D533K9aEuX/6d8vP3wcYsFaAToO5ffPfrvwAE/muMvfv2j3HROfyW/P9YUynMj7nt/wMG7XaZ0ScDJvj96rtvfxdR9D8AiuA/xNd3QsucD7d8Z2YBtP7mgki/@NMv/@WPyBYzyjUaCsfuuqgVUxug0myUSn6X7Y@SQ5RfmIcWAvBT@g5yqDm/7yBve/fDb7z70T9998PfePfDX8IOU8qV0jtpSV0t1kAPK@XfIxwGLLxPOAz4GaafovEgKfUZ2Nhnvudnn30mNK8U3N1w/wpcPyMn/jDuhbsffK/AD91xOwS7YlGzb8z4xnXfNUyZcoGppkjQ2AikoHyWTVJ@hiY4cIlfcIdAkw0yTvBNrug9EfA1@58ZJwJLYRj@4GVQgZEMfjw/CW4U8pBMajIJ0EViGeOi0AZ3oUk3SjdXYliCySQ1AX0XDJBCCrwepFi1Wk1hxCrPD1h51mpFRllJpapQbozN46SbRQQxeUBQIGY1dcSaG9UJj5hCeLUAHSkBnY5EVRNTxepDSLA6ecgQFgInsK9eVWvF6qSG4N5yfKQmqQeUJwRWTU1qb8FeJZgQT4g9fAtZKVZTqVoRE8RC8upJN3kl5alwVPYUS/l1AF8cx96@z9hHoloUm1w6RITx0PhOzUJv04zkNvifpjb84tB/YKTfBiF8jZLyU2Hcf5sE0W0um2IAgCtJsiwz@OEs5za7D94TDipFycInxSGkiCKIAkIHhiM@KSFF9ZsiC6Qfq2588IPAsDDr6@tCrCZmxUOZUKcozD0r88t8rrjqVWZioSSis0Fr5oO8QPwKpb8ex9mHOOOA2Ucp/rt/f4N9BMWk78xNYFIq6@ScGIeylUqJGsCvOSnhJWggAtApAboS5EmVlJyUkE4zJldj6McODw/9TJDDy6qQAjLXsiracYJkPB7HIIYsp@V02v/K9CUH2TfI5Ot/5XVELl0gyjQtVwFFqcLQiUW1GhUUYHR8@/Yt1AotVikfgG7K/HUrWq5InuDAN3db1jTYW6HlSgLXy5layDGWoCFQeJIsKbAE20gKfIkzz0TwJOJasRincIB9ObERLGMqqEQOOPwZq2FGg4cri8V8MvDcPWS7h0@e7D09GTYaTDDoQlSjOXSdtuF5CfTbefqQ73LQSoVkrF5H0CdlDRmMsFfOEPs7eHh0cFxmvNB@FSQoYxWafPKLWVKF2HD4YivmL@MQ8fYdRzzGd3lWtoRWykLUWE2ItQ3UKICW8B9@FeGJ13vgTEDlT4tiWi2gGpekQV8mfN0ZMzwbjm8khzaFi97lrS3CgFC7lGhoHo1QWwWhVvMXQDFVqB3vnUCEk0OmahlZqH3GJjImKF0LNatqGXZv1F/HlUTiaUaMlGm9nknjn5bNwlvNFdJqfrOxtmZdSpjmKVXbJS4JuwbrpYTF@Ao8TPiKwL4CTvBAGrjOi/mL7A4OK/5KJzyFJcGXO4lqHppZUjiFiubghGH0qQyBvEGrj/yE2Nrnn49YrQa6tHSwL8SAXfRZsNpHMjtyX6Z67oxdg3x7jHXMT028V0numN7Q0qfQdgAdsevr6y5AOthnWk0jK4/Rwfd1m1xaYL6e6ELMLperb9XcppDTyuW3WU0TwEGIvXyp67VaPdO4zG1quXwur2ULhfymBkgr5Qr5YjajZgqZvKappVyuVCxtXrME1KyuS7VqVssKZX8NdzabEUjB//@fux@a/tga1gC5W8oQjDoYc1uKDsYWGPNbSguMJhhLW4oJxnEtq2a2lHFNYMIWPxaN4a7rqjgyJngKI3cTa55hdWXcN1EVKQFN3PKPGa358Wq4AcXRO1XcmoubBRLJS6FT7Thtuh9O6MgtpzOVvdHUwk0FluNW4yBoxQMPE6/cxa2L1TpryENnCB2ilt9M1dUMsGX8qcW0lu7IbcvQ3e18OV9ESzips53PlC9oZ5z82ZPHj0aj4ZFB@xa2c6VyR8azT/CUgu1iOZ9v1OuimKpTMg28bpK3eWltDdqJoXck@HYde@RJWrEBkTumW63G49tZVZPUcjZTFK7D4guAOCxTTcCYKSxLGpF36Teqsu3Y0IDLaT1tXlK5y91u93rjMjWzCPqlxG2AkWtJT7cuQ2tFioQrs3FaMmee4KJ3oX@59Ge0yqKWL4qVemVm3yyIlca1cH9gdEwddyucZi5vxyoAo@NQY5DQKROuy67jjMoto@u4xixgVi0EAXmGbgfIiddhcqcZTPHydnIFDAQ45JgDSuWH0NVohV4dmEJjD1p9vbEVHE@HFKppkpaVsqqkZvH/DoOG/@8fXoN/Dd8QK6sJJ7hF@ymwaOhWbPYYt3qOHHbiOHTr4QOjvSTEbl@npYi7ruN5f48wD3T7jHs9NPm5aKHXIx1vPPEG5qi/JMTz4QB3dxvuPxqEvUELMkgNmwI8gJdrOc6iAJvs@bMlpXwSnkQKyOBHkULwo4OPH51Evid7O7uPhAJ7cPj04Y1P3g@UZ4/39k9C6yb3DaLmQxBf33v8@KbV/@QOnx91x46LP2H/8Hlu9gqdcKebkINnPlDoTED8F1pJiMEB6zWW3wwMqoDro@@BInbPN@YLM2MGjS/4Nj7TC9fr8v2aZeEk2NunM2RALYO1@SZ@1AzpgB1fblQ3S4IwZLZzwTYzrONYlo63yHbXwLGv4z4lA4Uniy47xqQvHNfqXJgdY014gluiSipelYmZEB4BkMG4TadZQF@Mx7V18H5XnCFpWWODjfEO5SWO8EEnNLpmrw8dzIUTBBBaus5oRc6HPRDfiD6j1Q4jnga53fKxbgcXYoI@0mPFyr176jNXLGVFr5Ypl3tGbW8ChMqeQ8PR3Wm6mBfltrjP5GasZ9a9xhDqKpsrqGunmbNyzhnWdDxa7PU4lauDmDjqtivQt@XLgN1acTu3m8n/1W/@@G//@FdLGjC3DQVeMVUUcSH2mirIJERrpWK@WMpqxXSxVMzl1UI@n1a1NOgfmyUQQTNqUS0U8yU1XcyVskBxJfDNlzaFGF/lpmwQSPiWAazdxssbt0gOl/sgcPM5MfYmoSdZTA/tYyYaEEcUUOUZ0a7PDbMKXQsue8tuMoCoszaL7e/vZvb3RfEBWnAZwG5GFDtoyRczmc0HomiQz24RBQbR4XGKeAyOOOKWTObBriiOOQA8QVYU@2jZK@CgjSiaaNnd2d/HdLpo0TA@BDvjPtxiBZZNCGajBQRHAvA6hAbBdng6OcroHlowSfTZ5z674CeKHwfZQZ8jHowDeBSUdGdHFA@4ZWcHfXap2Hme0U/QskOPKLpgAeIXxR4Yei40O1FsgRGbgCi2wdSe6uCGF2XiIaP2SBfFKUcPIkgUJxRab5@JYjNwx2Q@9XOTR@yWyaLyUt8nSwn/RFELMo3BsqElK4q50JKDsj169KneB3rt8Wfq8m8bSvroUVY3J@O9/dbHH7d6vZY73dn7@Ai9dncfQe8@HbutXsuP2GrC40Cs3UeafjaY3nyg1AfNZlm3Fnp90mzmdPuGV3PaNDCHEOs15Mx/epjQoLkLXruPmvf1RfOTBLCJrX8A3xY@DwbwfaC3uFfwkBd9J62WWEHyR0mYbtGGlkgXWqcHett1KmifVNcYiyfi6Wm9kGlUyIMNQObNVK7p@uwEvnUcZEheTuuTaqZRnVQ3Nb62pZsQTyda3hTTa4NttZQvr@nbqpZLTcq4o9zpxllcUrdZQr238YYlnia3tWyuLJ5ub0tiXW1sa2qxXNh8uTEWxWQZ39vZzTIEzMRBQ8dXsr7Z2N7MR6JsbqZ0RStvbiYr14CPEXTnLVT@m4nEhaGfJZOYXVRFoQj88u4pldOsdBOT9KTK88Wmycqkqlb4uXoscwtWBw9xHbdHjssh9gDcZDtTpuvBRbVUFCF9RUkkk8DviDXBd7aS7sXXTs5OTj4DTgh6u68iP@N3zlZ868ePdmXQmn0bHr4q76PG4bjyLrKrOR9@NmjgdAJiufwI@k9QSgI33NnjOpa8N2kbQ1RbAo/gSD3ZPwhNPnk0B@e4D5rGvq/reBU6TcduGwzPpjU7TK/WwKR3WIJyxfTkBfXczVqt2qwO@A3ftTDWJ4wObp2BOfB43sPt2hT9Ene7@B7Naua60qpOYhOA06wySX01cDqvtFS70sEjaR9UH2DkShO@rYpRNfCeczEmVrrbdpWxse3pXeOZ4eJBBAeH6yBH4BaYRJcZyXV2Srei76Lwfi3VXGbPcvZ0PEiAmt5KzjtFrIiaxNeCIl/Sniyc87@udKss8TJZeQ1Wd50lOvKD5Hau0kk8YM0kuGRedV91mcYKuQrdFZlASNCICDd023iyWvsERB8O@Kxchoz4dXwGMDElAGt2yENPDs3rSrtqsYTEJixJ6MlVetU6xr7C15Ykig1Jql81hJokvRBq0E4r05he9cYtOsecZVqqlilUJuCmbuYqfahY/eWk4laHY9eoWGD1x4v41jO9AugErAGYN1eJd7/wjeSWlK9ytwqBurJA2mjKzeqkYuPJSEAS1WwVPFL1XCYNSi28NtPQzWuFtFpIZ9O5tLSJrtDHp/NpcATFBqSJhJUQGRPTmUlGVtOqoaYTmVdm51UyfZYAWYVQxpLpkbOHl6yDC1QSUiVZ4auzZErbsBjUgsP0LYnIFDhFBQsGOO@zoZnuI6gjQ7coRjIpsexGwlpPYJj1k/Fwr94ol/cmw6@BV0J6vV1IbWZSb5LJSmItWfWM10KtItSQq1Cph2tAs/5QGvPGgzrUMZjUTa1cr7ewiJuZdDaThdKZzavellgTG@nMWkGFKrpmJB4xzjG4iDQTcmZuwyYK3JYBVaeWtIog0@hRtqhJJSW/kc8IuALRjykMfbaGmGSJUzHYZpmIxze1eDwZr@BA95roj2wCLyM@FgemGr@nbosgf4llsaRhgBlLpJ10magIdi3gYADLlYTYpXB9eb0F2qxC6wFBcmRrZJLk2n0hVmYM5MBT/9wWZY2xD11mmNqqveTfU1wZDXAFOsMQJE9a/mOYqIKxT3HX8DaLQ8Z0d1DXtGyjrm1CTwbcMQiqaWoFB/djuPZargGKvUvI31aqhhtuPmHTqZ6SgtHme4z1UusCFTp2cwJvp7rTO9oJFjft7OL45akgimIlLsYu47H4NfwJsfu0y0fju3xYLLLPhw9g/1z8fiwej@NIMSDqbYyYBNu9DIacynilTkIvc5ZQbyTfPjWty2JW4uMKwKOur2PrClWNv2ui8skrDagiZjvBNgrQhXD8BnqrfB5HYWPKq6H3uVbMPjk4tB@6@wbjmyiKuaZYi7GMKuGmhErZd82LzbUzFYgiK2bP0jF2P0YLqcVSURM17lCJsTMprpb5xovhcenl5sviyyfPD58f7gux07WrNQcH3Fm4GOyt/dWvQcB4Nhdn7LQam1RzFX8pWK0mqVsaHpW0ycrA77tqQcpc1Thd18ijoIHPu1/4QW6yVQS7llHBrmn5lFarqRsaS8aG7778PTwX43Lv053HLO7pU/a3f/wjbfNv//hf0/Kq@HXFo@HhzRiERKNa2IxdXg4vL6/h4X75WCPGM5XbTIKZTyOosZqialnbtiusrOj6xmYqp923K4ofVt1UkzFPivkTIpv5mHfle2mZIngFMxbkJBawSmJ7R2ZeU@9vIbWo4Z4wFv5tGV4pJsSKT15dMQaWdq3T65kamRSFld9KbOuttMXe4iTBW2mNvarWcJJZxZ1kwRj6Bu6YwYmkeC2lbMQZqD@sVr@uNFKMRuFBUXxpGBv26Q1aP11jpdINpw0b/owNj/4wUuDggTWwGRtfeGJiI6konY5/otKWwfI1IIUNBXJ2mnz3C7@uaYW//eNfuWpeNT/TQDsslQqqFvuZ@rOfQYAVpxkEqh1NNuCxA2gIVUK25O51UG6F2NhGGZiHDxREVAlRgjB7Nqj1aBPOUeqhWmry47I6CQq2gZud0yRD0wE2yYoghLImychur50mGGwDr8aAZitcCl9BL@haWRVYqvCVGShwGEBn6rSbnjV2h7R3IUHx1Eaa3YMokMJX8CSyNdqk7fNlCViZsnE7Ks@yR1gjCYkNDM/Dc82gSxG@AlH8Ywzxxm8dzxPAkKYNHYGMQSif5NGpQ9oNSNviEZrkmqDS8wBpxnPHI9kgRwtfAdGAsGCCxMDMLQhQAZ7zFUAAlCHhAzYbbItlk@zSTKUqs0PTrnHZNh4Ppwd7mQWMhtA6uHc@iFzBcOAE8jtenIV04dcwCGsRxwAIh8GnfqugAWB0sqEIRocNvDcogEUH@ySoaOzevVmuqlWzk2RUIoR/Zg5x8IrqwV6cVwAWaE8fdcpimuFxdJXANSQ7wHiKsgtUJ/Fz6CqRqExE67UgwP97Ey1S5I2qIo8KFsCvL94q2oAyiIxo53XYZltVpmqbSRZmvg15b1Om6Ai0UCU8nXwka58FnteQw5/FgmPpgRGdRAcEfbq9uZmdQY84xjPB8Ugjzgz8Tej80CJkaAejIHYYC4piWhS6a7qgrtCcdHAaWiKrJjHa7PQ4ygctxtZyuIxZyyfxQ7EwNIOvjud@@ems0XklbQcq1Bs6Nh0URgeZ4HpzoAjgUf4ZSzzbY/sC75Dw64YiR3Pk0flKSPmYYzr4jC7fpLg4KdxyQacNcJNmRk9m7UGHaSWWIEKjs6DsEFySIlGGWyD7Io5bljGALB0bBm0k8sqK0gPJadyiA7GemEBX/X0TehXbU/x7TpUL88xUTvAMbMnp4n4jfrxADIUtbH58/tk/fMpynDNmmWcGH@dNzB3O4DGQ/kGATQNmZz9AbBkXNmjZNMuAd5qHgt8mfDa5sZiOxF1LTJO3v1l1LdHEGr2iTsZ08Q7Tc92O4JeeK8FXeL2pFxzvQoeUgF0OWa7hH@xQjeOW7fDEEsE/qKZKZ6TIOH8wTID6GRzwgkZh6BrnDFVXAfsYYJrt4KgEbMVQ2q9QB0BtD1oWnvs2cst4wAfkxO0k2tD0fAZvs49YVhMwID99xz8pB2Bg1VfnoYMfRMVyeKMOVIxMg@bIV6B1Djrgh1vLffLD@AF1o5nO5JuRN1vzwWGnQ2lVGW8WgSUfsWDrQHqmoq@BZwFyuCAnawkxBWBTYlLkoMP4N6NzaheIl5TZbUhphhB8VAMUEhWCS45Z5LIHATwe6B4/Edg/Fe7i4kKmowrHrikbHl6A4OHNzcqwZ4K47CgjYzD0r5oz8YpRH@7MJPF7T/A@7@0J3aRdujflX0HoelV/eUgi3vXi2Dme4/n@vQEda4TnCXlEUPsm3Q3STvirVTj9aY30ZUB/ZaQ/qRi/RiCMIZhJeppupwFYutU@S3cvOhXf45waJACHWjQCRzwe1A0sAy8wmcNuGMIZIR8NvVrWGc2FAiSRD9DOkuYlDEJOA6tvH5oTiGQbF2zHdfVpgvyTGBoJODElsYdNodsnHzBCN8Mu@VmV5qQ@bcxFn4TRoVMLtCHm4plFwuVqoPzgUvSfcP8J@E@4/2SWaJBsfdLgIhk6XWNxkOrxqLsgJIKZBmGu@SGfMx@CDDI2UzkIDDmdc7uGX7tKsQN8cxvUYzUgDKCJISDcSCj1l6f104btGRcbjZTSA2IXCRFQ4wC63iCcXnRCM2LfOreGjjfnZOMJh9Ar@flGp3bfpwZOK1jGsIKIMDi@TDyUrjfw1xBwgcAvMEBAOQw8UTTYGSXMZCU8KJc8gXDq4gzHPGN1PzMNkr58L98NxCWOeo7YKKBGBBC6h0WCbIIPC1oOv@4m4A4vXAfCBGEluqFjgIcjxRtxwOSNpsJ5TYUqKZIrSQqyCWhHcbV6syiBP1RF/YZXpJjXfv1Hs7/2wdnvQrtYnHsiWN5hVIRoU8G1cCBC@M2FsMpq1Ui9Qg6UDd0yXOi59rh86vfWkMyGEqgZPB0sgneBd/gmIpXfTvL6of12oi2WQ1KYVqtQxGmVN0veLgKUcoSH0Tw/2jQgBD8@ZyAAI7MwmuFHm0SjTapVzjjYZEm0i0gmJ5TJCY/CQ0@WZLLhRwPtKbz8HaunAdIpLtYTAZ7Ku1EQg4Yiw4t8cUr7Czy4DWdC/TRnPIeowKchFLGRztqNhanXI5mOMK0bAJAQbwHo8JvzysJNhqdKoS3kURyVAY/iNp8MOK8AAiMWXOGHmyZCIiMdGAR@MUX9ALRdMVUXRJVGefEvw39iOnAMfuptx8x8SHXeMZO@8feP4thAzEYaaET6UDM5ZMioyTy3/VMBozJHDC@Z7Tsg1bUuHJZYIGyDuzL2oyoty2kpAx2XpuB9Wv4d08NpMtAfcIaE3R86I33k5HJlrjSZRHaL0uc6g9mzHTyGP3LAMch6Hcfw7PgIKrXt9GzTM9IMz547M3y1w/DPZReicrJvdDxB8IcnuRqLoDldoajbbOINn81mAhfWJcvhol1aZ4fkGY8LqP@CKRIf2JMP9HCYcFpfGO1R8m6YeBa3H@3EbJ8lDoe@Jw6l7jDgYW2Q/8G3DxIM85yZ5kgnAaMo3Rol6Cz6vjNweiD1jT1ZwNg3wB/MYGOG9OGQ8pJmOqq05ciJ7NRKEu20nvSjfvLBUdknWkJPhvG1eQBzyEgz9yaOEbPuguSaS5Pj0YL0jj88v8fR/B6vzi9p4TfzzFXzKvf8sKSziRkECDjLRvbubGDRgW91bmVnLiuhM8pVPMJ7Z7FDS786mNMdCLrjB5e7QB/p0OaBLcz4p8vwv7oCg@h771t9Ol57fDwFfjPAFYkJujnFC6Y6ExD8IJkUYguSC0n74XumBWHx0qp9FCFAjCXGZeMhptAwh6B2e@Ex@wHgO2geV1vdontaglXlngvy5J6n2Zm2vIoeNjuGpU@NTsIPmY7ADUp8BAob8av3KzgyOmJ6Dtf1EtB3JUNf6MYR6TxQeQnJ6OnzZHI5WfEgZkg9NFJOOTxYjj/0v8WacYivykerQQ@Ix2M4HHtu4vDncDqc8nOyLX7hjc9Hef/DaxIPFbgbIYAH3nuq6VmyyVXs8ygRFuk9eoQwrDxfZDzGNoCIx@XcrsMPQ9HdJYXKjUSqBrUszN//sLjGzVU1HqGKgCb5FNL7keRdRPfeNBchNQ5sxsJ2P6wLuQUZV2e024koRO6yssYc@xZPQDcap7OX9CrNBQw1jEmcbmSSuk3yRVJAzfgAvjjg9Cl8EWDPGDU5QQVlwzEt/yYqRj4DfRiRWnwXENIBSgSLHOV@NiKhhMAMwS@vwzTbS9Ns30qzPZdm2ALmk4wEEtpzSfq1gNWzqgosoztawp3RC3Vn@Kxi2/DYju7iaMVl3IyXzTSLn8fLwJDjRry8lwCmHO/Eyw/J4MXLx2Q4i5c/AcOsbcWv4uWgWWAAF6xkuI/uPgtHezte3k0kr4WRfmZ4QbpyvBzWKYTZ5lbCCKACyw1SI06x2Y5fzJFrQMdGQmWaIcV4aVSfaBwmTb8M/PMbXeg2CPTEMc4NCsxSTJ3rNCI9Bk8Huo3gtPEFLbns9@Z7h/u0uikMgsmkQMeLxiHwIIbH4vPMiGcMfWlGA76QQeSb5cU5YpGe7D2z46cOFEqVPJ8@YU8meaCTIP86BG7MEqFrfPz4QX3Ng@AV@H75xMjL8nkrO0FylCOck00uyBYi9VV8RaGwrufz4td@tIZorHs@EN4bHgThtURgIzwdZDianMPEhs5wnkjIFxfQm9E4NCjHGyVS741oxBX8lrnEm5z9kiFjiDb@5KriROJh1uZYEHrWMw3eysJ@gXgxes14XURS5Y0PshDhOdDCjfYZXZH00DdSOM5u0tRXLOuGgrg8SeJc82wSIst4StNYH/HUQ@V1D89u@jD1NYg5wbGWBAKIxAxT4fzV@QD53eHyeyBQB0i4kcAiwXpxV3pbvF7Zy97IuTVL9nYFomeaPUwuFI7CFGYoB@0gIpmvorVbIj4u@eBCPk80hH5D2g/QFuoEd@Dtpm7BYaGU4J7PO55p4HimLUfUbYnEOpcDoUXGlHw4vOBhTmdFW51XXvBFVYw@NL6tWx9cwe58BUcrD@FRAdwbKOet3B3btMpl1raBbXMXZKlqmXFGTtOlYTXPHIHd09RtOG0LDofNo4eHTx9/HTrdzc3NpN9HT2f5w1aLY61hP84h01LpsD9YoLZoabzpBCe7cTje6zvuaO3UFm/xEs6sQRjQIZWA/Pw2nvR5WYSf32i7EI@HjWDUh3U2awb6HFdCUUfHLtv08ToChBijxIbuAwnEW8B3mrS1JN3p0WzivezNJnVfzSYuXmo2/V4MqyaYEU/@LLamjD2XbrLkF9JcCAIdR8AeHrIXj3ZO2MmjPbb/fPcT9vXD5@zFztMT3In@7PmDxwe7DH57T4/3mDC3hBIv70KFEvD60GgbeN8i0zKZHCPIu85wyvlOYjfJ3Y/1AXvktA2cptry9MH9PrfItjGq8Vh7oI5OcQzTpMvaBuYI11vQ7WKgxqJw06FNf7iyn0HYFui0A9R5B07H7JoQVkDdd2gaXrBPjFkm1CDw22DTb5oLSXiRGC0douv/cAXWBUTXITzO3QAYna@/QhRjCH7zWEdmPuLC54MxeLJ39OSY4aEGu4dPHx6cHBw@PWb7h0dgffb1g6cfAz4Pjk@ODh48Ry8K@OTw4cH@we4OOfAMZGSGpw18MfZGK7MgY3DCSvsMZ77lIVR/aJsf9UYJnl3otP3RY/GxjdzH1C3zjdGJV4Sxh@ILbrmkqQKWWN85@vhT6POZ8RpnOIOpYFp/ID736HK79QzbotSgsdSgvVWE4PjAhKQmaT5iMGV4v4VRoVMIEmROswA4LeLpmAYTd3GNCo5988MKqC0HoCGhNYCNoIIFK1VG99LE4@ktAlmD1NqWg@dK8tT4IkLfglHvB0tNKgJhzF8rg0Bx98KBjeNBaiV0ALoHB81PduTyACwbOvAA7P8p7mm32tiR/E0/hbBJ6Ib2FwmEYExiwCSeJZDBkNwcQ5zGbpu@19i@bgN2AvfM7o99gd3/@wj7KvMO82ufYrY@JLW6bQiZzDmTc4K7W1KpVCqVpFJV6Tl/wKVoFW1HxKrMcTU6vELxLNb4w6@Xgz06FhYv9Idtj3ax6xIn7jfqUk/oe70wdEOXbh9iLQ/dkOiFzSCgIiHlx5t5ul0eGD7fCQcykY8SybYNcqZA2LTxqEGavfFFqpgK3IB2Ql57FAq75GTFMRoH@b2A733qdL0em0BFpjvEe2Ido@SUtuTyQd@XRP4ggz4xIN7VFsdDl9uVq0L/seWg5PZUjZ60kaQ7C5UJ2vcQ2J5C4B8BA4AysZ1Ok2Yq8khFMP22ZGU77ANHot72DzM/sHPrqunHCkirLfvX4OtXRxLZje2TlJ0iYQdd9NUfwrKSjjLb/SGMcRKrdMMMSsHmRX8wCrgP7XgL6MSJpjnIjRMb1PZFEVfWhnRI1tjr94xKz4GL76n1HJjyMbUSx/PZuRZf0dWjwPkwCbPdHaLjnfevfePszMVDpBsf1S@wEKazclR@TkaECa8/rUh2/CHwxsL10tbu9mnmjy8uXlvIYoFvDVVGh/gfGBPrguFB53xksDjEdZccaeq6qfDqHEtLGzwpLXGUK2CwD7wIYF/3ulHUaWxuPP0dPWaS3@nj7W2JS2VQMsmLZMMLO5JurqirKl0qcyakCYghOwFZkPW2@uISTC2vX6OXDPZCESjSQzmC@/bEZU5ShKjWnV@1QbLIOzVld2v4jtgii4roumH0fjH7I/fZ3i4tbzm5yKBEGOS0lYh2FeSC4xhmKTRfTYHbfRgcyO/Hg1t/EDueHn4I2u6D0H4It8zy/bB4WjJgPR7sHw@A5cntHwILbXfvB8yT5DQ0zemaOd2FtLamfbjGL1N9R2MPwODcixoUDdSo7apHR9QqjLPNBRwTTLQgqh3vVo6ORIr3J1AW5B5uGVpSDCLsefE@srYNeiTssnrRZMZe5sWT@hKzaFP/HhrMM4l3j6iQaxBX0kMLi@hi7XYwZqknZxZaQpD1PQlERbk4dt@UDArrEvAd7AEB2ajTjAZaM5uZ5sknCE0jcEk3l9fGpg0/WVjz3I03VQ4nJiDTJsjroGfJ7P77yOvjDVUPL7AwrA82uAUraZhvYJ9Qg4oHkDGbjffgA92iuhSN7HmBnVa0Q8OvfHyF/fMMRYzEi3BeCxtiXS6OJWq8Pl5QyxwySMRpwENLT5nIFs2QoEQ8fdk0O9SJJj07PgXBIhPvLnxtcgUUP7uTUxhRQ8@TJb0gN8faAmFTV1ieoXZWwi7en@kJ2kKvJcVDsiqQtg9WlfnnVMWzRKwmRfOZjVGJAHltdfXZ92AnW6GKZ34WNs8hSfk5uhzA/j4CGU5CUu8D51YPXJUeMcADpGPTejVgEgVhqTNjTom1nSYjEz/AhfVCgAwGNcfrIJO1OmKcwG02dJ6RTOiUZaoNxhDWDeVRM0X9u4erQ4H83frmf7w@HmyYCU0H79Aq/11/GPqRV54RqcX4hK6t8W/@cNijbOzPdIlQbHJjetDZjrzt2OCVW4WJdN5mtqQtvZPY7NZVugaqhNSLWbwBFrV7xaR6L1Momk3dq@5XxBIFO2zHdJGpYcoxZM980HsIAZLBpJfA6YN8@J6EG/AfcHAVSCATefPZRBvnu7gRRWDVXKf7bKRZqJSthWTvt8Om18MAH27qSShS7lMoSFrYyuGeM0uzni/GygNy4aBnQyk3lcmmqCh8Q4UuQoqD4N7E78aEhZ4aylIS3Ws6fbSPwoMtf8zaM7Kc9HKF9fzaS4ta13NH7mX95Zm71CylBEy@Xu8yvBretH7r9C@u26IrBr@ej5uTr78LsfpcPMMLP59yxNnCWilHQT5fwN918TJPnCsRfEXRc09TQmT5rkAhFkW0Dy/OC74ugzbNG@ghkeBSsXSpuBBd7Ealy/raWalXyhcv672zIjr5jZZLo@XCso0fnsIsCjKGT@brozOcU02tq9@7FniFLF31J11DBLmGwJd33jDo75cP3sS0cbgAQBWYtPUmhTrf/jqH1mzoe5Lt@Te2VJO5AjnWwgWSNUdeQQX0eyd9MqpjWgFgBr3iwmo2HNPfiWPN5bNXg1GfUlTAQWQtcRvcWnPKjSlPGgXIUg9UWEK69D4cR3lsPBjirxO2os4UeLlWQN9JxwBRx5IkDlOnqRT6FCKi0perfmaFWd9rXiASeN3xLRUTm5t0@TGwWpglLR6acnhDcpjIn@EjHoDAz4BOG7AKWrmH5PZhQfPxvYAP/IV0VCPykyEDeYtWipiC5t/iG/k3UflNIAATfo7XXFmp4pQrL1hIsu8gKRcwbFl844/HDOhWyZ0yh41F2FxfKQJOluJEI6xWkgm@z90gOZlW8E@2IFOgt6lm6PwOZyeS0Dm1fAuRltSllLSFP92omG0Uy6hiKrNBirnvUgM1XbA9eufDsJqIHb/bBaSZFnMROfCR/Htl/cu6/rCOdZ5p5Dk9M5WeiaVnOZ2RinJlYYKPMm2YmVLpb1G@O5GKsrlTdZUELV6y0NPNLCxJorzFh/KG2VG/EUSZt3RXMlfqhM1YQsZI@Tyj9zllPlZGM7hOr3O65O8V2fMay1je1/H68deSHeST8ay0NUlwabYXdF9Z8qZcmYJslgJqCsHF6VI9oQZVSfpgSnECKzjU89Ow3SpFUJYLSuLQmEltbb5OZeUi45WdRIO9GKcG1owxYlCJ6lwmwo3JYRHqoeR5AwTBREYTauRuqcITWXhigMVc86pa9oKcGuDQtOQQL6Ff5C3@UYM9jpzKl56dOMeYj7nx7N0cJxAJ3fnUbDLFpQm6i/BH2agHZpGo7kkS4mwhcWBogXWdPvtgt1ENPq/lhCkolKSYortOkZSOMhQU@97XhZh4Z/09t2S98WCNPej6Y1HGbYZHXlhWzMF95IejECM9Ubya8Gow6OKpIy34bsiFWsYMWVnF45YIojGzZ60qWvZwfhefpEM6FMqKQ4R8gwYiUUJ41emgMxl6wPZvULSixiUYZa1yb8IKDRgzz1bYzdwXVyGfmsJuv2MiwT3HowcpHQ68pp@1YI0WwurH4qa2A3kZJenT0W8EY4nBlLZhWX@@Cpq/7bzB89wXhfyzgkGya3kcnM8@ex45WAGRVMIKxgFcLTy3LONsuMlnwxkE6Ip9nOg/AG/6136v51tlmDEoYwiL1tAfXvutrGUd@foQGOEiK@PJJPph96@GTVbuwKLLA2ZEL@HQ5eMw4DD8xfmZj4ubdFbmWnhoFZ02Q1dfBy0koPI4affxdJgOLDBMANMDC136IyDKkiPiKNHZs8SF1i6XqIgCamCcE@NsQpOh1x8FTegZ0mRZXQDFxyBRZb1WAhOor9n10Dk4OwsBdI@JKKAQUEdJD@FgyUPzH8JByIapM3ZP9UwOpF@fxgoMd38YgPSNCEy9QsUM3KGDj99Wa6J2uHf8sXxUEfD8/ujwQ3W3siu2P9EZNx6UU0xd8fZwH6SLPk3nU/ND@JAq16BkihKs8sEnUfnl/VGlVhOHR6L67v1@FaAB@KPywXG1UnNF9WBn/2SXTt8Bgjg4PBb71XfVY8h2fOhSraqYFZUTh3viXeVo5y28lrer@9XjT1TjXvX4ACvDU/2yeF8@Oq7unOyXj8T7k6P3h7WKwIZZu9Xazn65@q6ym4X6oU5R@VA5OBa1t@X9/URDDz8eVI4EGQkYrdyuAJblbdjCYk3Uzt3qUWXnGBsUPe0A8QDBfVfU3ld2qvhQ@aUCzSkffXIl0FrlzyeQCRLFbvld@Q00zrK/QxXol52TowqGQkJK1E62a8fV45PjinhzeLhLtK5Vjj5Udyq1orD2D2tEsJNaxRV45x5VDTCAWpAOz9sntSrRrXpwDHPGyXu0d3Cgkz8CYQDLMhTdJQKjGQS2Foh0ePQJoSIdqANc8fFtBb4fIU2JWmWkAlpU7Byb2aBCIOKx2UxxUHmzX31TOdipYPIhgvlYrVUc6LBqDTNU0SDjE7AOVHpCrcZ@Arz4EZjVUpzrUneK6p4o736oIuYyN3BArSq5hci281bSPIsRdw0lStBHnYF3aSpW2tOfrn0MNTmtkZmto9ERk3YOdyswI8u4Vako4QRmnfVEKCUzDWYanQivsZA1Lf/8qtMIeu0@@pjqYqz4uAw7Ll4v4@DdHKfWA7crSf0KFUinG40P5QZsdGuNhuM@pmQMje@VkGrwh3I5so14mQDuvFHxs7HBdN@MEWrrqTzoJEM9PIDAnEz9p2z65l36jsjlWr4shs77CFipjkI@NrnAoxQQjeTsiJeKRFWSZoLeA8kOVNBW4LPNBupJ0TKSMvVD@NO7jV54cjA@gHRmdVcuh5tYQiP46qtquBIKiUB/ZESCoE1VZkPf/61j583qcM@f7fT7LdtxVBnKO4J9YMd2vlP83O8kimeS5QlZOnaWMfxDte@mJYw@f5YkE7JfskNqmY1/GiP6cRQ2HPMBtaZUFSmrpdLSfsrF0SLJFTK0BbpXUCfjmu9d@ZfqR9zN5VeeFxPf3@rvPLbQXhBD0sKEV6dyZ/Tz9owzwACjWBxAkkBGyMjljDLK3kRnvoGMF5jpJmih5Q/M1Rc@zetAEljIXnlds06cjYfB2MQe5PCbo/K77ZO9PRCdiO3z9dUXa0VLh936xeXfT1gPxY2lqGMDmMdhnUZJxijZgYUPjRQjXnfE/sTAuRxmxFjsqtPoI8Z50HYbcUsmFGTY3BBv2OmhiV7KRzqkBAXgmLcUv84cmZIB7FhTHWzNpTemJb4HayXiAWnM0p1Qr43xD8LWw18Ncd0gyUCSxSiSLnAu7C5I7qX2lKkobW4ocA9myaYUH3MYN00DUnWR/Sx619Kb5G2jF0M2ZcTxSt1OJQGJ@SQWQtlV9Hhkv6c4I1IBTNHD4Msvkt/g8ZMMcEfh7rxwVB7VgIx7uiTqqSNltGx0XUI@w8tyMKiaqmlToJbfkUjR2JPqZB0YxBgNhAref4I2vnHARR1HJFklWcC@XnTEN@ZUDN6BcIqSY@U7cO6s5kgoRRU/RL6rqBSCYekgJ0y1G12HpbJ80nEsFDljZPopehD8fyFNZsDfhB0nQI@oZQQBfBQlCSrTCravRJTgRh00GKcbETXNT58iMHdmx1zohsnTmzH71wAJZO9M1IdPFPawbc8gADI5KjbM8atN0i482Dq9TjmyOJ6T9JqXA1vIuUJNFVNwM2tnLi27XHW2gi@OcFjXZFS4D0XFa964ndOohy1TYisvnoQpBueo@B@5JVKA6AFPXHrBVqtJzsrLUabkgAy1ZEw4LR0xCZald/ee2i0JI0RmTPbLky9FKAC9hfhMt5MuCekLNs@NR1ykmVgcUxQ8jA6O22ScfGTIunMyxOz6COdJi5QheI/I6AYniC5Dp1B9ETRhPyFDEawksjqM4gyiuHWyQFqaVm809qSZRA7V2J/0OCy9z1otlSPLAT4khqa7fFa88yaAcvdxzWYWyy3V@i7aLmJlrJaQ5fHOlGa/P4Slo4ftBhzdYOJkxUepdPB74dVQxi@E@SwYSo2EWvRDNbhs4t07TTMcEZ5QC4MReiu0ssQf1KRLHy1EOTzJOLMmbGBexaNbSukYjJcLwt6MUjaBJhSWlIi4KdbE7S3nYoLKkKE@UTAI9eaCbDapHjx30MPvpj/8Ded@XAL1Wn5LRyY1QJIukDup2qMYj80RN33QD0mjAV2BGhBNiQIr0rShKszRLyQ7SbumVBQdE2OXUkt@vB7NpMpaCiqKGFfWDsy3loHORCqtyNCgOlhoYWWVUJm14bq7dzNG0ULjx9YiddrTImWDFxGlJ2rpiE8sN/XTJ3ySSv7SkxBHD3zBM265BEWEcc2K56rTco7wQ5uCj4E/bJk6UVjJtLwBqt9o69PvES8q1aEM@9f0RqE/gR1AMxeMcwSjYf@pf9Fr7PS7XifoBx7s0zCo@5glHj5O6BE7rDPs34R0HRAltIxMrUn0zPFlOAwbvutzyaIRmisc@QPbNFMYDSflCw4TQZpzNAKMrr0k/h4kY6TpMs9Xo0JW3P@U7PEKTvHess8KswrziT4CkAJuK2FBwT6kI3JMMpxPi1MZzh/KYOB4LjLCc@6x2Ith/BJIRMcwMYwVMlNmCWYjcGd2L8b11thtUQzCIQZa8nd9vNgmtOmz6@FNwiBFXqGlwIYorOeNonyKMsY4hPgwuZ/cKy/@xdgDAj@BfuHZLG6ZxQgk4toq2lLI@xUZZRRwIfPAgGQ0SWKQYkEHZqFuDGhjnIQaT57cRw2y/IFFkQyzN8WVOCJt2PjgrXV2A0ROY@LgpLIoFh2K24FLkPLIzt/PsP737Gdp8OMhLmvOUDDtSMi2gfR9pGoClfCu1oR5rYkyx1T@/ohZWXlsryUIWJplcmbcGWyn1MqFPFACnl/xWKs/BGGcSlBPmnoshqP@YPGR1LtXdsyMzDaL1k3H@a4hMDNbCSbLpRaRtjTBx0nRSuKTYJo4xcjSDHgIt6/0rNk8ScRxqYHjrdSYfIcO99EsspvSk4ru7xaPfZwUr9GiV000ekgR7hiktKi/1xvQ8Mb9EkTC5O1VgyRGA0VGY8KPBqgEmTSVHk8h4j6Je4IeLaAc1tsC2pn9cy9Rk0ZyKuSpSooFuUR6YuB2dNoEuTRoo/EFhonjFa4WUnrBOXYndJRXyJxjkGFMYIC4KvYzkR6KNbhRZyX4iG4HaNsNtBYqoCSCpy3TwkEH/dcEo6j8UrkjLR4ak0zhrMiQxhoS7Coo10OQlL85vNYbY4IyRQoY4jNIoVs0JZsuHt@qn20L5AMIXJqSpaVv3sXGOGIZsIE/ZlJjjGvgqCpZMjai4gOhQaIBxgLsUjpdn7eruPoLhszxaN0ghxFsIPizjT/LsgSG817La2pjkXFrglkcSW4ebY7IbHGRiKH4HckvhyIvdWnjCgB8xhjKlwoAAcOaEvZ4KEChd0zOiyEq@wgKlgo4LOEjRUWN7DxnpCNRZYbnq0aO/KwcL00YmZlAYGExO0@ECKxZZmeJoMBENxMXI8eL2e2JcsCCWPE@Uxy6QvZKnIa655iAdJ9y3okkSr0g3LzkYEp8vurEEjV/U@rLvJGaT6YCfTSG9Uwhmbqej6XGql1ZiReNlQR6OGatsUQghWMirKXCz/0j1xQz5Lm2CTU2GbFVhrTPxvuuYZcJ@7bsr6HYJKdstcZQ8EzPcLX9avAVK7Gg7A8HYBeLdGSAsdt/urXKMlVhIu8KoLh0ytnF5g0hrVhTONVjs3CnqyLt6QAFak/bb4sPx3t7sbCv5xNlaHTpD1fz@Twy8bkZ/F7ZVqMqKejn4rlz7atuNze4@dPww3mOZL/v05UAG2oH7UOXwKAIs/1hh2@GQBwgK@bOSEdW3OtftdvmFQx4QomdB93GOWU0BEETUKCNXj4ckwKIQMoJ9gs2ENv3RejRd@PxQlNCUcdQUBpNgq9T6vQMyIMf2mifrU@qCBgKZmXNBPOWU9r6hjMI3mxCnUXhi51vkXly6q3f7fZd8REvFMZIAXN3yQJ7e2aBPGfBE0by7r0KKR6tK/zroGv4FWMWk9cRnJqY1D0TKi48xsY/8juV8cBO1T@nYFqBJi9jM5cxPrUrUp2UI4PFPwIs8yGg/ajcl97AbhKdkplhqpcjOHoCjJ4V3Jl7n1gWh3Rikmbfz41EnY1uloI1QNMdWguoWPbUvdSSe7Jr4qZOx4U20jDPMCROGHPlcSXQ1exfJxavR@3246QiXQPAHftDEpFvQvk5gUhnADQC5fADemIU7X/LwLDeSwQU4QUOXtYxLXewQAMLWNaTZun3G7tcLouFwfKyKJe34SGTEeXtstjFD9vbYhfet/H9aWlldbXIMnfX@QYft9XHO7ENMEjDudy8GO7CK6SV0G8MrbWxixdypQW3uNAobW4Vw1y9vI1u/fD0t3//z7/9x3/lyvLlf/Blm17qn3WmbDabW2h@W3h6V8T3@u7Z4sJ5fWFwttgpIpf9naKG96ujjBeZj2aH51aaZwHjK9mRqn02RZ@RRYW68O/SG/4G0mVDpJthLi2/hnxzFMnYdNM3vvvoR3kOW3h16UByKw9IpAHoBNXx0DtNHw3wYL4BSgIuaAfK5flsRSnuMRyMzqBPVdIyEg@tWa999GmJIimgLy7MWJmgF/o91IBf05qXm2dZHvwGo4bk39znd2Fnuz8WS6e2WMqLJVcspVL0U1h7CV@dhVyA3rmcDbYDqZQLKdHRApoZijCghR7tH@iunQS5LWuBruxBSCpMBWVmLzhX7/7IWYYvXAs71hxerClYRUKHTFgk/W2hdwfd8g1y3KVirja0UGjIXQxVZpyo6P7FJZAXsiFAVPMlE2SjD1XiSR95JONTTn2RfW3RbUIEGMl69GaPxj1@gLlooSdtnmN7KbzmiMzn@SvOjUV2hia0MYXrjxCgAxXeTubJk3AxvWixlbfRSmome2Gb7ZPMx7YOE3@kbNO50B/CYAK25jYJt9CTfi3SkJuPV0Qq0McrRlWppO23sIwil1fdUTCQ7gpUOw6ob7q2Ox5J2KMEiOFwzP6N6RFGigIVKSrRLXxZ1kS0@th0Hgk96ZoOHexk@eTIIELusw1j@zYxtp0ceYkodmAeIKS0KV/bC7qhjLoyJGJ3vOE53g7otelCtRGfm5E@D69STWDcb2ukswSZTM6j8QxNSQ@GXufSc0X6oH889CZVmLZg5TNqZh1oIYZgQiRw8MmqZzVPIcwtkl1CFNFNIcshvLygO5HXo3HfprTPCXapGgoy7AoOghg7ESX921hfJegYcfUPdIKJ8pTw1qeRUsSS5EVLIwkpZbrN0DCbGjqWqsEcO3rgpCxGVY9MxQuy0BVOtJd08AuSvIsxAmTdKekFKF0R1l5i/Tg7dfyeF5ucBl1LOfrnioLnRRzPdBUlWyNZ6hLUQnTjHWIF68jP8SgQPDepcEbWnG3PnYbyOre0OY9QkG9ti5/zRKAvoKMLzMgzRJz0AhaWiRkqugMjK6pk@Q8Q2l2vA/hNbrwJsuJp2n41n3Pqn097Z0v2ae/29KtDmEiRrGbZjEjLw2wlseRYgZkx58ZelVVaqEINnvbiGU57gn1YDBIAIjm7/jl3dpsDhE7TeMP8aZoJEusyxCT3cH05BJ@bQjMdxyKXtuacJUd1vv2q4AiYW@kX@5A/OPwLWKhNJanpYZ8zbAMo8tP9/YpdTsLc@kr@@UrhOeyEOv44M/SvcL7NhFfn/hiWEiFuZ2HqOf0a44YYIe7GoVeEj2NoJ19rwr4noXRSkiJUDnOqx9JsBWWyzBOQH6hM4VLRxcXReTw8fMQNvyuA5VReigXFpoMG99k4f4b9S6zHC1GuJb1DmCPRyoBtREiFmkHI6vKV@zjUUcNlkfycsmIHY7cSEOjeXNqYLXr9XkYu1pzsYhEX0eg1013Pr@eTY3RqiMZG6IJcTC3Oi8LWqxd//e/D39Oj9NZK7uMQfkfp39Nr62l@hAd4e6bertNb6U3MtnaXnuRgDwyPL/76v1B@608AB1Mmm/Bna1XBWpuktzIlKnKb3lqDh8LKCtT7f3/5C7RhgXdseBfrQsMVhFhRUWTH6xHvQrqoYit5W7oYiRVyzEIYbGEIe3N4QcOo8cp6ntR0aWlVce3LyFfKHkVO8WSYNSJTIdZkKHsKWBlxgRJWkGGQyoSiLQzbDWW2gcwboSm@PMmuhbAD@CLNOXSV2nTjSYgmQwu8LYIOtLlG2M/zw1b@VUqbd2yklE1JUS0hcWsnZe36s@L/Aw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/0h74u)

bc in standard mode doesn't support `#` comments, only `/**/` comments. It ends up executing Pari/GP code.

Pari/GP after encountering error enters a state in which it prints standalone expressions: [try it](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/X5HL0Mj4/38A).
bc also prints standalone expressions.

Pari/GP treats `3/2` as a rational number, but in bc it is integer division.
So `9/5*5` is 9 in Pari/GP, 5 in bc.

bc -s #332 and Pari/GP #292 code:

```
382-9/5*50
quit
```

Answer (score 3):

## 334. [HTML Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application), 14970 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@     <!--    (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####&:#######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//      n&goto e 18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnn n M n M M M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
:e
echo 330
exit

*/
#1""/*
333
quit































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata#8;&&1Pr"93"s>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[s]pogr61!\0k:4op>astdequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8?4C05在ｕ/a> 892g=1\'   
 
*/
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSqW6pb1WpWlLdun0pFgskQRJXIMACSIkslSq6e3Z73bZn1tPTdrTbHt92z3i2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEiqyo@IjY2FRCCRj5OZJ0@ePCcfB23dG/zsZzG82FPHmvUtZ8zGhjdmXdc8N1yZ3Zuxu7rp5bWsIGCsXbc/GRr22KsIMaYy5o11d8ws3e5P9L7BYuCrsfl7z7TGhptmnmGwtmE5FxCeZcw2LtiB3TG7AImNnTPDNl8bLoTlGLtvWG@Gb8as4wyHut312Mg17TGF5hl7qsNLb9I5Y3rbG7t6Z2w6NgQVGHtmW/qw3dUZRR@5Bk9UZACqc0ZpFkNKjD12XM@AHJyO4XkOepbBU3dN59Huk4@vxVcz7GMdCjWyjOm17FWVPTcNt3s9hcY@PXnw4Lpvln0iOTZ7cLNIao7tTsbOwfg6/Dzb7Ru2zjS5LGvXAwuAzLFhlTKlzEIQhD0wXWhN3W@1yrxl7MmwbbiAfL8JL8zxQIYEJw5HOHNsa8aMKQCDMvYgmjFmJrYWy2cyGBP@j42OY3fn4MHLADgA1xiOxjMmMdvxaQCCHJd5I71jSF3DMofm2Ogyy4TSOT2/NB6DBmdnxuzCcaHhJU6KVBBvZHTMnolJ/Bp4AhLbfaM96TNnMh5NoHge65qe3rYgWnvGukZPn1jjNGtDGCCP/C8Ghu0XybT7WI/ncx@EYEMX4KXfVAE3pmUxKM4ZFgez9tg2BlygP0ZtG1RKo4ug9ufoAki65QW1X8x4IRtM99R1@q4@BELtGoSDTw@eMq/juPAGP4zLe8E6MB19zLa3WXz/yf04q4dolN22EKK0xi4ZY7EgkJ3r1sTw2FCfQd72GDoXc6j9ghQCRGfxjXiFxbNZpmVYLsdy0NlKTMtnGHSJMjig12pZFX4FppVYTgW6z8fTmE/P1fumZXAofcfqIaAiUqyWZxrcMzmWVUvxNI/RoXyKLFtihSIr5lkR7mVW1iAjhJpjajkPvwL8AEoZSqHCL5vjuYWkgSQF1WB7rKcPTWvGoY9GCL7D8iorAkQoqgqQtRJAKGsIYfGKwhsPALkD/RxASpZ5hizDCLkGtpgCD2VrSyG2hfyRZ@kNDMvCXAFZgKZ8iRUh1wJUPAc5Ay61khZUvj@g6lO5ihn4QRmLUOMSoDgD2Moguorwg3dgRRrwHA0YjAY8Q1PBXwN3FqFCvAKEFaC9CrkAutYl3AKHhbQqIhOZioo4gGTQCCwLTVFgOWjiLDZxPsugnFCAYoEBXymprJRjpSIDdJUzDFCvQmGw/VXgZyoUQkVg0KwqtKsKBVGBYFQAqmbzTIjgVc1iOKTNQlpAgZqDNDlwQ7uoBfxBOmh4FbJUIU9NK8/JC8qm5aGS@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@CyMJQLrBh5B8CxfAWxJbw@Mh1wLqOHR@HUC5cGJ@h0mFNAKRFOBmbQwMEOgeSYIvnqNDIGalk7RmQMmErJ5M8x0tyDVGycB1R3CMX8eCdBUbG7qSDWMO8TZsoCEYUD4Ub19C73E8Yu@z0VIefC0PfyBdlZXRgxGMsWkTSgnHTAOz7QkWHIKKsY9geyE2ezEwUMIHy@04PiI0GexBaIOkcdoeQgCgIvaZyRxYI5UhAwzOLmawzGjHwB0kHyPNBpgSjtfOFyV5DoDXwmNWZuO6MTUfQEuYQYo07Tq8H1PvaGA0ABBt2WWfWge4JjYzUI3Qd4kSd0WI152@bBsSxDaj23tOvs74BaIexvQclJZKfV2A0oioQKnSbj/u2DpjCKnRGM0ILgAlT9BxHRv@uY3hELCAXhV0fM/OMPnUN6Ge9OTMaohwDVAqyhQ20C5zH714IHzMUllYGs/Kp4GPDhq7TAaqETg/Nh226y3qgRUSGfBQT9U7HGI19OnGInZl2RDQ6fICiEflKPjDZGwibd0GqW6QaiBpSTkQO0M@Iy6LKQBKbjrzWV1VAMrCNUBhmnLNYsxvZQ4zza7mLLzHOQgleiivKMKIugXIiMYnJGFkJckezM0BeOEZuQ7IK9DZ3crP64BfN3h0yqRfmjaVRge0IshJ6YTlWw5DgZ90EJI8shFVf8MCoCx63gNa94RLITlhIqxv1lRVdBqZ4G9ChYztLoAIyQ7gYZTGE2oKI8Ri5hm6FxEjdxVtoI2TYcy0aBzIYQ0cjx4WewZnODFkab7IIdTlc40mEY0USNPDFoRWGjDgO@OMx195GFmhU1MWwp4JUqgOnACbGdQngeQ7PMVJg6vUEyy/fBbF@Tkwwltq2gYKt7s44EKgeDM@Q0YyZrgts8BwHCT4GBYOJTHQKY4Le7SJnRXRQv7@euYwUvTdpm9PrCksHPeUvPOFcd1kPdRUXhA7oRIl4z4snq@RPKSNBouKMxgol5XcRIlIkGZo80QP1BwaJB8Bojmd2JyEudDExzcTJuFcSk@DAhFxGY1/VR@PrpfsC/JBohmfQr@mtyvowfEsS3CX0o5JggCJjgO6CnAGdEGT1crnb1tkb4B4uk6Z7lBqFS3qqci7My7C7YV4@IrAs0frKPAvP7ZBDioxqWAOMTjWnQWIBge@JCUoogoei@GMrepC0x8NIruGeE5smGliCiyJJdhkK@jAAJKgwJggfZscct3xx5c6dQHDZqNWA2ECaArbZTUZVhGBGRgZODZFlkkb8TOSxczzGvpFIQn0x8hUvDYhNQKm1OrscD1zocfR@JUAkQKtgIyUHiPXb@Yl5Nuleb2gbPTGSiL0OhCazMxarAgz@vDfU1mE1voBVUCHiiFUkXkxPoG8QL/lig4p@NNfwUPyt@UWJtHACS@DT6lIU8aS@35yg92YdyxcJuAs6O@dGbSj@ma/zh4wo7csEQae90VM5EOwOHA57unvysOb3RR6otE27suBhOR3dIu9NjC4GaR8d3DvaPfp6awkMy2xXrnsoZq5UwKF2MpX69kTJyVplMwpjDvh@az1sTLgYRxT8YCY504ioNOvA4DIN0Hl49Ml1lIAkhOigHMCNv2siDY8DQpfQ1r3BtUGY9VMpyDJMEsRl0gELYIYOLDqG60F5nk5ev8bGu16oke@PJbMmOgcQeCoHdpBOxsBrAlgQ1O7xEZHSghRq2jiTOndFYwbl@Ril5uuFIVE6QjIfHz7YP6oR2IHunRmWJVEUxRuDLKW7XRlo3pp0DWFZHGB/4OqwlDwvOMrTVNalCO50FhA8b1u2Aj4AQF1HdphkDYOqeQMo@971upGv1AkpgN4JwnW5MioPdT60oJFy4BDXQZV32ShKAfPBKvRaOmKFoYvDViefN4q5cnTY6szz7EaBDkkoNp1AbnQh6MyT0EeeS5G@WO0X//jRjYJ7JESCKiAFJfMsJlNeniWg9iKZLO4pe6ChOZYhPyeOJzIxqSjxYApV7nikfEbi70/NcSKT5E81CXEh993dA@1@ENmf7qOZDFIaUBfHkcnt4ZJFxwMasR3L6TtsC9Jw6TDIEMSmldXc7Tv2jRbS0ROrGsM1EOC/OHGjj2CsMV@T4kipouoqXz/Rbe8CuLRayCKSCEMESqH48hf6uQ7omtf7@ODzfRhE1HwmE7ozdAEKImkIXejqRHzJg0mQkeyXZ2kFw/WQG709CJAiCxJYaZ/RhQl358FLPYljysrS@EuL9FXnBsa/cGbXSAt8OGmBI4KygydPHx082X@8@9npWMvnF95zmXIBEAf5tUEWkgccb9hbt3jXxGohuBj0DRe7F3CBCSgowcT6xHOBccsYReYFWEE1fCUp8VVnYMe95PXKXGCo9IXd4ST0GDsfj@onBEW7a6Ey4vIFOBzPkX4G4/HIqygK9PLBpC2D0qp80XEsva9QOhgYLEtRUXU5OMR5DW9ZCiiMNzN4Cj65BaLDjGYQdWvogPJCi3rIGliCg6dZK8vsD0AXxpU/w03KIQVTbZQuaAigKyth3YgB0xvg1n8G7SRy0v6KqpU4XasZLaeIQbSF7g9xN3oGqE4JGK0AFclrr@z0zukdNgMujZCuA4kxectf/MGxwGIgSNKsKer5AXKIW@B8KfIKwtGrCc7mApdS8plcUS3kFVDLQE0DmVXCOTdpqI87A2nsSABPcno0bxChwp7X0e2evOU7gsKC3PcRVDXbeHF6ajdBQD@9Q2XDJbXGrNlQm8kqu5lky4@frAL1LlQPaTfwANolJ5AmPdkKftbVb7Kzrk69q8uU8XDkjznSiD3eBUHqtQP8umtE@x4mUKKBytZCXAUjv1WWTAhZmFTAG2JKgQ4FIy2QnoLlkkDoRfEQKAf4ViQBm89m8HrwhewIH0GlG@nedOIezfijXIOzpd4IkEiTzR3k0h7OD45hdAwpH7k0NC4yaXZhxHEeXff4bCUk8pcvg/Sgq4UQaFY@nJG2w2VbIAJKReo5cA6gK5w2HcxnGVHpB0qDDKlMOPkAEoRNqwd94DOQmFdkl1eE50Q@i1U6s50LG6G1DVaS2uaYT/Y7ExeXBc1utG4QPavxOACNKhfh67R@2DY6fJaVJ6ZagBKos6ExdHAqAaQrYgUGVUHna4@oC3o4Yw3dKiPh8gvAl9jdPeBiHYPPF0lDVKKApPZZfOwqu9Lnii69BmpeI1th5XejS@HU6CcBAmgmMlwLp1kSfwaUpBNnSJGe03wLBt4LxF1hNBsPoMZAYaJec0aGfV3n4xphIlmlFdt4HBi@aScu4xsbG/FKvB5Pg2sHXNvo2kFXClw75JLIhfFkdFGKNLkwtEEp0K8Zv2oEkKfJJtLAFCWH1@YooTcqlWwzrTdU/6nhMwlNAZiH2BI@AE48WauhM5kU6xe4ZgPye6Tue0g7xx3XHPko@CoIBPzdx0GWkADqPUrzrlFF3XQ9RoY1F5RGA0XMhBs/bWROm6eXp93U6VU8jamTVb0G@iEwr3FiKPddZzICwa2Rq0jA25KNbKVZbdfimfhWIlGSLMhITyY/KiVTOsd1Im4ATSVOT@OAUh87jc7AJXjTtJZMhoiCcvRM0DIsKxGXL0uQfzvZTKbikDYZTwNbrsXjgJcOIsGjSuOMACeiB@YUUAkdE4a46JoCMUhanMLu@rkxGszcaIRw1g2kbJxBny/rQ2cgLh7lkq95@qhAt6DpB3IvjwfCLU7eobw0mnHuLvCSnioLW0yCcfdc6g2dsa58KoPSJEeGy/hGXJEkGAkphEOiaj82PezCum04Ey8607h0AhRzB9@TwQSYZbD/Jg1UZY4EozNwWHzzLkBn4XoPDiW4dCXxBbAAQLcjww@ZKEoluFgC0gVtTDGBL@KmFT4ro1IhOOsJ5ubzhdErOcytSmlYBjMy@7bjGhKgBFIItI2ENh0JdebvTTmgma8b6xJ@KA1pqHibBnDEB5ajE245u46sB42GkfSgn0OSI6MrWMA/esAeZd4WrtFVtgRapXXcAYwQUBvkxFrYWkM/QHG8UVceTyGpkMABNxrItTsQOi9YV9O0QiffqwRhSBWA7AE0EmqlNqi4QZCkQmDSb@R9Pi0U6OhPDu/v87kTGmxxeMV5tNbQ6U5ArvT1piPD7qfZPtCTaTtDE9AQpH99Zh05zphr@fCyamaGK83mcGLpNOdzfVpmbbqO03Ysmgpal3Qef@J6uqXzSaggdPfTxyDrPzs5rsmVSCRFPx@uzRvnIZdny/F5EF1zpPXWYHnI44QpbuZFHLeCbW3IZvyAAgZM/E1t0EaBfxH9gy6Fayi@fwn9h7ihDWRlfxaBXkNPP2KZIuImN9wb5Hteqpkr9F@pg4XxVIrHBcd5aS9VjfzPx73egneWvM8kZE3W3DtH3nyz24KOGC1SnkfCnW8LcaKAChQn3AB3PZ7PvMK9BgPDClYQj0AwwVUyGNstFJ9AN0FJnO9CM0CQHuFiCHFoXGJjHZA1vRvTFtCnRhKPLcQ2qJ/AGKag5CJsKsyf4q5ST7Edf2nS49zTAdWeZk@263wxG1Unl2ttCp9832wBiO16NdiTtCoa5hSPh9EIKpUNUlA1af3@RlXD3RgezakLlKQqeApoDVMtI51Oi/tNxSMk9Jh4ejr9KKN9BsoH7h7bvKP0jSpmtxJb9M7noTsDYBssNV1EGbTDxO45Vlfii17Q/oyrS9gQ/p6DcP8aMXzwMd1g65qJu1n8LYbALiO73m7AvdZ09ZsRIvvkQkDQGy7Zm7P0@RvWgBHsXPZGljlusit57LQGWPnxxLWv76jjIqXr6jNP8Les1Nju0cefNjJNDkEY6riQVeKtNQ02ZIIcDHIP7nsFF268GZtjGthpY4GJ9VVlKNSU1jyg@ACDZ1BlYUZ@jbDob4w387r0DFA8EwaW3JsN08xIXsk9Sx@PDZvTFl9NXI1uvuzjZ1Oj7Hf8NYQKy9BCCwiaJoZBEavs@OT@/tGRDBTqJeL7uCBTgW6ndwYgb6yqdIDJaOUr7KNunH2EaZKohQvQpUCZaPnpgXirQNygTkDuyAr6hpsAzySupXTAm5avKCEXuHwE4fapzphwFAJLGEmoEwGrLC3/M5trTn45KyzOUoRJQHfiTgVwaybliW2@kj0YN0gMhShxrnvSZtvaZoLY16aaJPpxzSGuBYPKRFIg1KHRYBvA3Si2yGpv2YtGRio3U5us2azyFX5IiDI9bd71N4LqPj75chgxSL/MB75W1ru2HTjIgWZuMRUvnwo0K/h0C4V1J@3ZzV4qbmpiMiys9Bo8eKB4vZBLtqvyIgZ7nIiF0Jaoxa1NixunItV6Rkr2tW3mUJ2gAGF9cBkywWvJNmpMTSaDknFAz3UXVecKe@p4ntm2aB9szzL5lrBwsK74iPEhBZiJZlfFjkF4w/4M/QwbY775mW8p9jFB4TTQgCaFNSOPRJJdIjIJlRpikb15gx4i29QYkYGIe485fq8CnRb44yMHCvvI30sdlTmIafjbU5B1nApioLwtrv9iCFcMlPNrMq90LkbTcZnTtM8cWkUKXa2MrOZRzgxTD8@smyl7pjeg20LUsAw8rraqdN6w3aPbkgi0mOIv05MHTdP7EjY0p64c0YNm7JfkvLg1ZSHbttGb2H1a00Q3k17dElMqlyhyr902V0UFJOBus@C5JBrwSux5mpyT1aD34AQPDIvAP7lONK/69V1NbAHvMEiNIZX//K/f6AL@b7bOAMYrnM8MHS2QFLClpN7KxvKT4gvdljcsn3afWKZOiCHXbSA7ugtV0q3QsRw0Le1LEsgbQ1yo8FscaBNvIIuuITNecr7OGDyXZ7Jsqc4Gvt1ZFffaLi@eFS0qgbrYJSRwmcs0KBExWd4IxpQv7EQUd2S4txcq2IrFiJh5uw8m4wm/gzh8ayOaI/yt65t@zExeb6sGKKR62zTWNLmrn026jjQ664dicWFJ3HntaWVZAqnEX2RuoXN59XkFXbMPw33wXBVtPr4qF/S4jSo8e@KNpDbp9l3@Rh1huCYH1@L3VVFM/8xT6FiNNdOi23tSog8dCMXfY6HgDlYpgjTzGpotvT1DUWjw4VQW7lcAjlPrpFKZ7IoF69FodXrUTyl9ubw89VTucHwsm3lQ@C5Zic/NUYX9fbO3tCoMV@ZQtyStG3GuZObLtjvciBqulFIa4xzXic6Xttwc@zggdSaW7s5da0h8Xo5gcWLVPLc/bDw1Ow6IAyOmFmVVC4aOyIBBLDPYcDfPCDcp0y2yqcJchsYuaKE4iEuhazkLcDpj3Ii6gqbeg6HxDaC4zTZCJLKzClMd5wJ/K8WHAWjC/L58RHu9tFTvwZwkq2PpMI6vHA4WphxxSvMWQr0wPYNuyxF7trSg44611H@xCwSTidHJwdvI2jMtx2PHdF@HoL4LWOD35QQdxaWp2xJNsUfda3hQsHNi3qC61XesQqmv6HBb2eoTt4d833@@L4cLOZSq3sKhAvHHsVX/uZKvnynu2W0NREfIXNw1G3GuGWKXsSl/RWd17UAxwOXA5TV7kClRSlnhE4grMsaFnAt9Fjz/DkPHKtQGQ8doRuI0SHeYoFwCx9jlIvbfJbfc@ty678eUboAt3laJSOOeWQYMVnS/0aRMy6gfmELNZN6fRfWsiTExlioah@0vDDyNvEbJeP9CZfxqbPrz/7jkgAdewlivfc3wvUqN4zS@rWUmOqjsxu2izCJTG4H0PULV@Sk4nqLjZoq@PRkttOqCdmYfrUfZYBR0aae7UDoM@VA@VLpFUlqQzz2Dfms1Jq7h4bazWi6TyfgCTGQdZ@FlnSaVDdN@YfL7QsbkM895HhfX7tyIc3kehJboxsaVLEhbpdhT5HJZsU3bGM/w/p7ctO041oe0FDDVromiGEiWtIF3XYvdEHf8oylsPnXh4YRHu7dq0oKPNr5uCfhBpXldo0cXmt6rNSVcSh3iMtfi6/rpm8iy1W254KlwnBPiW3qt1bKkPxuiyiW5uLbXcQnVaRuWzh/TQm4dvLKcXQtvkWn4S8C4ZMwXiucL/LFrTGk0A2SZXdBSBsbQoNc1Ur7e/WLiBY@VkaYO/lYFTw2jo0z3jc6qCCMT@IKN94WV6YiwNHZs0K/GuHsQ9RQL96f6vqs4cLCWuBTJB0O9b3BTF@s45XzCAvfocLVu7lw@dVHh@3I6kGw@vbyaJKBTnRkzL3guBfh41oF2nQxvn2671vk7OAf6Hr191cbYm0OsPXAG9sAY8N3o4duqzgH0OOamSdYVHUrdH@AGudFoYeN8FJ@WY1nvg09kjZxROk5vaZn28Ugtngf7ILgzvQ0B/uPWyTt9zHkHOlb2moExgXHJc8bOyJDobVVUCyd6@H0VDw2Wvv@uM0hr9XzASPD8u8K/Vbfs6854NKJHa2RNPLpRUolOQt8mN/X4hhfaaum4ffm1M2zLvqfs74ahFfflLKZtjjsDPIrOKdvoO@3OwLyt0G1DH9vmmRJM@fDX99JdETMmk@6jt2yZgF53JiO91KLhx/g4WNXo/uwRH9ZCxxp5ZdkMHR32lkb6Wcfjs6HoYhWcEI70Rn4kvEKH6iuvJuZ4DjSyQyqc3uXLEuhYVXZ/T8ZKyYpOXszZsL9XYyWVkpCOArlkZEDgUVdlu7h7LtLFsll@W1WgaC2pRJHdLh@Cbn9HEc0OmpF5W/BfoK@FrVBLBzl7MOl7Nxkmn67vgoiGt9XTFrRDOjJlDWOWbvuPVWjWLAWPTsKzBTLXxFi7ppJfu6hC8VRL0h0THi14QNNNVs6hWebI43cm9VYuxfk7pEAXv75eyHEzW65M@w3TNXp8CQRdt4mIQ4cWaUEGkTq4oI8z6MjMueDFGZft9IGpSxabRw7irhJblm4@Wt784ZgpffbE6Ou4g/uROcYtoEuogkh22aalW2F/baJ75tcmULNVxIZ2IPgypBs1GIBvS@A91vtm5@FCQ4SF9BHs7x/ljwXyR6@bbXExMD3cQBU61kxMIclxIkaqa4HesCTm9Xn70ATGvAPxw5VLYy@bW3dGMzyDNiPXuml1c0yzrP5zleq4amvZ2kJcTIajiec/lpeBtmhFZ6GHZ@TvXZgAXHoFrJUNdGu8fKY6MuUKUpg/KM6dq6Txz03L6bPPSxkGQhsIYSicLyGcezA8P8V9Qa69hBIp7/dc9sSJDsnlFXsFbWtkmWTa5nj9bM54jHuEgidWho8ceO5BeYR3@e6HQpBOlmPk0e2y/vzA8y3jO1DesTNxOwY6QysmUbXAz9XYC/Y04zkRB62wXES1tI5jQfcCh7W0y3QcezKW3Im9dlQorB0VKmxaKkTIgCW@tv/4WTJKDbQH/DYp1ADlb@JZs7lr5YaBa0Rm2iCIreaji7EDXeI@t750RBuQb0mziyaiOsSu7zvL9J2nM9cYv7fCBMx/MrxvdHDZ8Na8nziPHduB0WgEjHJ4ZHBLAgsbPZYnxGSP8Kw84Kd7azbHBHbFIMSlDX1ktKF9rbnrfcYiDvi@PtZXDEU0N0j6X@i6lVZMq224X9CkX8S9SqVdLNBDY0q6xWqC4X1QGnc6XCTG@biFPrKwYuONHMfmd@K2GXioj9dzFRgK6Pb@C@Uybu9fmBdYqp8tVvXwnO8SMbrc1MWqurpG27H4fc2eJNvkewJ01zQ85RFaTiC/Qo5JIH15a3lIcS0PmatGIMme6x4t0i9XNeYg1ekHbAEa6G7HwZUw37Fmd07E3MEtbDo8McA3DrQB8VPgWHpn4ptvvK1Y1rA9pNtKhSHSmkdGG88atclGyFif3mxMPjPkG0iI7OgKzQoE7Ao7dYElnoI2krx92FrQoxaxao7oRpx65XI5bdaRbNPovNZx1swhfM3nphfCoc7KE3KumKuOdCOaRVZ0Oj@/tCctbl0DgcYypPHABZ1fGa@b3g6MtyxZD5kMDVxkXlyFWSm6Ot6AKussX08PmatrSL4FQeAloTVBLh9KuyslTwQP/4f3vqrAINwq5AKDJsC6bl/Bh8JPXNt/vA8FPnW8cc@cHkK58dDBKnaC1cpDEnjwnoGurVWVgNazJxaffehH9l0Nu6SOSWQGV5IsYtdjQzLsc4nMy01v1sjhR8mUXbSnOja6km9dAVcapEfBqbIwmv9csoAa5Y242VNVOGKnhZy//XMZci8CzgDyljOWRh49lZH39ODR4Yk88tSl49PuAA9j3JDjFsw1aKVMZErqC92NrHfy7Whd0xsr945Vae/RgYwRVuCbr2hI8MCVuYXHynlP33qprugrtSAMNcbLBcSHJ48fpeYHP1lib@A6QyMZDd47Pk7jwZavHi8NjqZ@AL2j50xXJj/YV9XkEvJ9ZtPq4CruuSSnVZBODNBGgRgfcmsvtwpXHWdkdE9mI@NTGDyRg3vvmX1hZSWf6OdmH3shK69EFHVUVpYLuWRkZzYo24YbPle155k5Qm7ZoYfCHyu3o6DkkFXc7HLpYd2K/3UphmX8nQgflkjN3KTWsSlBz@gP0KXo3t@3YKqqrsLzsd6DdmX5lY21GGHZ@rDlnL/HUrLhKy9S6CWNgaok89Z95EVpCKxbwRtOz/ue4Gyv3AazDkDoXVja4S8Me6bbEq1lrRMvKpAaN7WtjfK58R4LUuEOn3O0Kb10jS/cUs8SHXImb8n4xI0k2du7d3BbgiMfl@tjffzkGXuqe2jaZH3EaImN9yjxXDL6QsJ5K7Srt3I5tesCKG0tvP5oeX@usGPd7Tr2bHr7IhydbMWhnUwWh7DwjSIZljk1l41VHT6v9XT5NqPb8uaHOJzZghwcNXnjA3r37X@hqpkMGTTCp5rhr7e0TNDBWQJd@gyt5EWDTg5C1tBBuUUGj@RSbfSRMcXtKHw2eJlSv3R8K6wZ@4rJ1cPJurDSmrDcmvxuhKEny8oZdQ3A/JowlpfD4EeOdTFw5D3dNbwl@4@XFmhdRcprKlKOcOfXpQxOgtLCou9eLeLj0QX/sZRaT4yxmxsNnLaZW1qH3R6armSP0QT7zXB/O4Xu0vaWvuMf@eDvy/O7mBhLM3qsv14eQJzmbGkQMEFjMKEjETeDFxdI2yDzGnbf5FYb2T1nvE9vSwv51MEd60uzvG@O7k9GqwsKLBE/GHCdiy9EfA6qsnPhsXt0hA6Xo@ci@hK9H/fGLfdfJc@ycFIQDZc@PNkl6uFn6Y4mdtS6s5f27XPwI7D8UKInBya4Ewk7lUomF78VET2CyQ8fog1Afm4Q4r55wzb844EQEJ6Y9A8loqkwUFcMPMorEAg8K5qwazU1X2Y7@MWGCggjScoRvcggU5BXg21e@mf9KhX1Cs87ihWR@WcxQ/uq3EYowEXrhlAnJp2pbHMMIZvBSUFG5u7ZG0YKDkhUaj4Db7ISPbpd9Y9QQpE2L58ePN0/Ptk9eXbcyDSvxKR/UJiXzbYht@AI@UfZrgh199EGjJNbDKajxhZkR6b4UTHygnoxqNm1qtUWqjavlLiDaTYvbVtR6MSsIl1B@SSR50ahIAWhF4cd1Jjaxz/wXOEHTS1CqbjJQYuUJ7RZhWWWZTzSgQls2n749S@JUCjLZjGUZ@wbeYUu0Hecrp@jZ7DbryDHB7sHj54d7bOggHOiuTC740GtnOc2gFG4kAxop55J@29qLO4niUNb1WrxB3FATFyOswqdUyb7u0DnEC3ADp5w9lNvscQmwQcMxsNGUf7rN5SruIxbSZMQNx4UKs58zGMEdoJnD//0x11unz6wOBJ8MscdUp8kyw6Cf654xalixCh1zNHqD@eQPXg6QBwaop9/jEig7xQAVV6QsbBrhqSSZNuFfwXJt/MVZEQEEti0xjlJtNnleuzcxNPDvAw9NKG1SMq4jYHMxslsF78KBDTPdPpYAhR9Yo@5mRrfqEUM6EgOGUqabVJh@acVxEjE@PYGkHLbAFbNPBsUPWNcYV8AneG8X4UfYZekevxGkgA0/xyUNBgPrUjEGza3POXUVd79yj9T@lUG7jG4v@O7p5l78PZL/lsP3L/M3S8UbPebNrrmZYkWCO3q@TXgBQnxj7iPfAzJ5mYD5ohDU2IB12TmEJrpnLCO0XkO/C4Bs53DSTQ@hUYDcoMW880F8PwMt5lAw34VRUGSQvFBpl3SxpRvWbpm4K@QL@RUBQopnQcAySJ3H89icoDJZAU6gXBujmovYVja3t5mIuoQRq1Q5S2rbNovsuLLsKCbEFe4GGDhGgzSQJJ5Cgir@8lgaEmpSUyKvCmuxpEtdR0YcygcxyZ8t31EiCwByOI4MtDE8xS/ijV2Z4GhyjZ@aSrytYZNH5CkwohDrqQo@CfcnzhjIJ@Fs/38hDtu2ePjG1qA8/hX38g@JNKjfLNnzQ9mBp@F8PuajDyAg8pmrg@V0bYVnyOIYwRREZeRb@MFOx2f2k2F0yYDMv3hEmK2wf2LSn8FzfJ67960Dpi4btsPkcXuHtsOKksPoDIsoSlaVlELyXmVcrmlVfJr5GcD1UGbJW8gO2BTwDI6hvmFM/J29/YPvnr49PiGBTyKGb8eDbh6fTt1KsnpRjN0xKPVWmySew@U48f3HgQNMS90IcKNQZLxa6Kuq8l8DgRBzvfUX6/ashJer93qEj/np26vlzerrSsaJbpRDjXzAfnSvlbpAZ1OuZ65VlqGrXx@XZHm8JQI6D1@tPBGURPJy6tGc7t@asfiNylhSUd4EZO3sBOA69Tb2lSQ2G9WDisWfp3xBD8L5UX7YnZ5XxQ3s2iICU82j52zuQkq3yMSEKlvkA2wSEFWgqgre98hl8DnhtI0/vVIbrIpaqgmUuBCZh3GI6BOgg9RIheZm3n0LRwOdG9gmW0hMBDELR0GBtlCI4fcuE8iKfgfC@AZJ/xPU04rU5k2sSSSyO0IVpqtM5oYwEsK0KFRdns6AU3oqTPixqNpsfK@EbiOHGC/oIORgmOwr06GEK9HjyODJo6Bc0uQGDAZD4vKZSngEr7NxGkKrVJCfg20nOhXXB5284lpUh4Y067ZB96eSKaBo32kqk0W2lXESpMdRTsuUpvNW2FtV/wYD4xG0f5BxjWn8wLoDV0GDdKYJuIX8WSlCfmjf/zi@Xk8KS6jJTLy6Vu97F639hkWv6iu5yT62O@dgSnNZdyiXL7JJcDvOmBupir4ck25LA88gb5EVkO5/HjsPgIniBGJ3lAfscTE5qa8ZEavidOEnSbbR1KdWwO0WSpF6hI8KEBmlLJHLj5@J3R7xhJKDYgAfT27i4/X5og1VFlugpsySbJN/KLUHkhcaBYnKYCGC0kqBLaGJARKBJSIdxKZEzikwXABrRW5ZBBtSTB9YIfm1xzECdWa1e@wyBfCFiVHsVyu@A26yBXLDKjvJjuUFQB7g88Fcj1g1ze7ATgD5VYWYnNGfpPjxSjfGC/IQ99eBxQnFrHgGZjxYABrbl@zM3Dxl9i3oa@g5aHKs5MHrVJSEVlo96Pvml2c/@VGqEMFzv9sCHRTZSFqvMr1tY8xGRp0a3HDImhv7AF1GPEaS41F0XD9g7tz2lTVtVTvJ/RbAWLmcADwz0e1AnBouTBYiV8StpzZ/@xn@ElfMbGpqmct9zwVz2eqcFOreZZnH22eStJmI1O7u6mDFjV@NT0Vma7ktu6fG4Ne@6CvnIoiy7KcomzFH2w9NbXCi1fTq6xaenU2UgsN@dW0KZZq6bPmlD19@tnb1tukOD2fiacJ0izZ3uEbUc2h4hqrlNnlTiEbOytjQHC95g9t1XVdYxfjIoudnuKnesWiqCiNeBP@KeglXDxSoy7X5Z3m27fJBtP18XTGTmP4@Ut2eJfCSVHCWSdNSx6bpqmw05HX7cLPGbAm/4ZzjF@pVEJivofU4H7V4bRHftNdo9@f7Osz7m/GJvh4MPbTPv78@fPn6HhOF3t9FPNhU@o7FT9epaXnY0zLaH/6k42r9OXT1vaffnOoGBv4OMTHd64eo/tYzX@0sfHRvXu5XBpQw91PP3/69d3d3dz9dP5pI7@TkzIb23/yxxsbmratKRtNz1Ob8cbZ2WeilsmJ8p/@KN56@vRrnlfP/h/feFtX8VaE2zkrAp@AK8tUcOK9BD8VZawz9hqusx7Df3K/7kbcOrrbvdcs9joGVK7GZvTXmjfyBlPrO8X/9r3DV7FxrK4pz114jmOvYoVSjDvBAW/Z4O08Vo9tY7TCVWym1Go1cBb/27@H9PWvAhwMmW3DrZ4PYBVmsbpUoyRvYvUCOFRNg3z/r298I0I8nE3USIwLrrusAZeYK2riThOuLbq2BbS2JmUUhcey7/QdGM0MppbuqHfgfTwYGw4@TP6wDTR7LVVB6z5qpFKpptyS4JJfkO6uqtopMAC2QFrUQwhL/iv3YVE/P4BH5qTzPEY0BURFdMXdvgeRGvd4fj3e8yVX9fk/9nUkxAobd4379Tqwwmw9u1VP0bVxWqlw9CusWBId5y4wiTSLn4px9pI98hunLmZKmphOp@@28HWKKJWmsTkCGccRiy1gNsbmbyzqFWNBMjaP86Hx9vH6s//1z77/Z9@jv@/T7z@hYTq7a/aULUh3Dl2nzi94inVXvDylF6hwplKqlJTW1WliCzhV84ipmY/fxPPZ@DGjLgd0cpoMZjtj4VWv443@/Tdy0fOanx9SD18oxjzJ@ngBUmMwBPtb@KTGeb0poeBUkxpqId@UOD0GdayXWeMuNJOoFctis67ltUNoOlXkDTfY9JgTAw2yAIl24NqAP/qHK3zdwBnlDfLbCEIo1s1rI8z31gtgVtQtLavkPyrsa0Ks0VCaRhMEWVYPgNzdqGyUKoWKprTWwGXVm16GYTz1Yueq2mm32687bR2utt7R1bF@Vy7KJVnbnuhTfaaP25P2tD3uTDqqKsTeNjbYEe8GTZYKrtPUrdczWW75TnI4@JMkZxoTYv8IV13VVLYFjDQDN5AeyAnKHf5BPVjsEq7m263G2y2gkHpqm7pnsy75pYSH3LrbTElXVw1wV6v@/3Y9dFbp4i6oXPMqldp@UZekxot6IwUgX/ggZQ5TbtWb2xQQ5uVn5gfHc0684NzdbjLINrXd2K45e/SDlHBJTYC7vVDWu3dTMrjuAoD6JggSyVRqU5I2kIc3fF4FkZv1VFApLANIN9vbQABX21f1q8b21dX2Nvxv0/3Kf4Lv1faNf3rMrxVx5uFN1shqJShXvX7aUOqnyqlPfE14l5U6@sjKKTjq8IR4MJgJMeieRkWIbbGtGBquysa2hNjLd1/@z/g7fffl7@FIz@BPiClbqCCUuZ4AN8Ye2@wxv2wb/uEXvKIPejyuo6fNbzauISjKS5lV@DRtQi0VkjLywpbTa@Gqo8xeQlSGDIKJWqkgtlLqTGOxbbFQJBbx8zeueDz@T15q5WKc69N4cvOl53mPIyWDG6hjj@lHf5CmqmVUSX1T56aSuZH6n192/ZOfX3UJsTdlQB4D5ucxjhQhBi0Rk6S6EKtvD3GDH85rS6hCnNc@k57tSqjz6mNatehwfa52sF8rl@t8Sn7zKZHO1v0tuKvwv78BlRFwhBFil3hrv8K/R6/xj5108O/oFf6xk9f4dzTGP/a4jX8nr/Bvt41/J0P8u/cK/x6P8e9ZH/9Ofy6bVavi5iWhIqWW1avNqUgoqcZ26qc/x9uqF//pd7/5zXitFpfiZCc/p4L6ryargEzPi1fvxoVYjW2qm2rGynQyalttg8NkGZdlBpmB2oXhqqWyjMEys8yMZYaO2gWXAX8ZcJmZHsv0WcbO2BARQsE1bmXG6OrBow9/PQDkwp@J20/aaqbDICMLJUn6wBaCB9eb1qnQAJVYfGmAmC@rckYumE38LEFDfPnyVNlqauUSk5FQ5Fbj5Wm8iUZvtXKOtWfGxulLFvNAT6jGlNNThc94QF0JHVdXrdb@k/utloJM9PSxczj/PzwcRl/X/g8PnceHztCB/8PDw8fQA@upuyngL3fv1oDf@I@dWL26c1ohrhVwrpiyvXNaz0roLqSAGWnol/rAaw4RnvWNUyF@kUAR7wKlvOrzi@p5ldwXwSs4WtV5hCAad/hPuC6AQQfS3AVc5xfooDd0Xjw/DV3coTy/OEV1B/TY8B/k6OjrP8C/@f@u/8fPWJIlGs1k4vJqO0FXEv@Sycuryyv/Xk8mEv5LYhv@0APeMcnlVR2dFOkSXI1Espm8uuJ@cE8ktznAOmSzXae083jAQ2JhlpQtvyX@YZ@QtX@dxqtMn@9EOD2dZjLJajuwxo0rb/obWhBOVunbSpvthtr8kx@RzfWdJEXK56pVdYvxFy2nVau54K1YqlZLwctmIlG@edUzO2oBhLZcLpmsVuFlJwCbgdcQbAnABi95gGp4esfngpcHh2SNHLhEPobm/jlbSGTomwX4@Zu4WBHv3En4n9Xd2U3euaOVM2/ehD6jEXipC16tVtd0Wy30z755I7ZE2hhQzsN7pvTmjZopp9R40nETT/C7SZBVQlLZR1qdci0D89VyxST7B7kAWH57u5Cr1ws5cBdKuIh58yJsMHEzHrsMBvBikrPG@KYiVrk@Cr3bw4tdXsWo2Vkun0wAc02CEHgVwz/urZbL3D/JcoVEKVX2/2obSVYHiYT/odKdTeW2ilt3QVbDv@nSC3ly9dKoqVe1S6OCk5dX1Y7/1Uo8fmvcuZMtA1pLmeqp0Grd3z3ZbbVqoijiqAo39CTuLuDHskZuvEFNni83G1jD5mk8XqneJfJQS3kGdODHk@IwTLBSmRAhmD08Ww@1F1R/SmND0OiJN6HsT3SAZwyHdf7rwsW6rM36eLE@M02Tmcyii1mMh9O90wkjOfzyQ8NXSotX6GOElxB7@mh3b/8krW1LLKY92N1La8fP7sVUfM3P3yk4i@9H@7v3D59BgqeP9neP9z8@@HT/2VPw99jF/Ar4vH@fP6OuJe8X7LnwhftaNwzdmBhG62IyuXjFvjDNlgntZ02gEk7fZZ7RgrKP9Hk9qvDrmJ7@xRe6O6KLvfvht9/98L9799vffffb337329//6Zff/zb8fgy/7/Lnd/9dOY/3n375L37n3W/9Nnj@J/j9Ifx@8tMvf/0b/EfvfwS//xLx@yP/F4nHfwLA@qWffvm9H/30y1/@Afz@lf/7wc3fr/xk@e/731r9w3Tf@531cb777@H3uxxWEPe7v8X98Hkj/m/xeL/8g3e/9h/4/5/4f@j87Xe/9kd481/@@Q/@5L@8@@Z/1LTSn/zbd9/63rtvffPdt77z7lv/VHv36/9WzURvv/Pu@7//l3/wu3/5B/8j/f@Y7r/7Pv/vfvDP//x/@fP/7c//wP/9BH7/AVw/@fP/CH3jb37/h/j/vd//mz/8If7/T//6b37/V//ml/4NOX6DO/7vf/Xv@P2vfuU///Vvfucvf/KNv/7Vn/z1b/z@X/7vv/x//vp//qv//vf@6p99Ez1/4yd/@Ye/9Bff/PZffOtf/sU3v1xx//ba@5fv4f/lP4LP@5fzfeC8T70@1OfLv1N5/j7YmOcCdALU/Yvvfv0XgMB/jbF33/4x7lWH34r/H2sqxfkxf/v/gEO7WWcMyYALfr/67tvfRRT9D4Ai@A/x9Z3wZSGEv3xn/gJo/c0liX7xp1/@yx/RW8yo1Gk@HIfrklZKbYFKs1Uu@0O2P1UOSX5hEVoIwM/pO8ihFsK@g7zt3Q@/8e5H//TdD3/j3Q9/CQdMKVdO76Yldb1YAyOslH@PeBix8D7xMOJnmH@KJoWk1Gfwxj7zAz/77DOh9UbBQxF334DvZ@TFL8aD8NCEHxSEoT@eomBvWNTtOzO@c9P3DXOmUmCuKRI0tgIpKJ9l05RfoCnOXuIT/CHSdIucU7yTLwZPBbzN/@fOqcBSGIdf@A2pwEkOP52fBXcKecgmNZ0G6CKxjHFRaIv70Mob5ZsrM6zBdJqagr4LDsghBUH3UqxWq6UwYY2XB1550eolRkVJpWpQb0zN06RbJQQxvUdQIGUtdcRaW7UpT5hCePUAHSkBvY5EVRNTpdp9yLA2vc8QFgInsC9f1uql2rSO4N5yfKSmqXtUJgRWS03rb@G9RjAhnRC7/xaKUqqlUvUSZoiV5M2TbvFGylPlqO4plvLbAJ44mb1zl7GPRLUktrh0iAjjsfGemsfeoWXJHQg/TW351aH/wEm/LUL4BmXl58J4@A4JojtcNsUIAFeSZFlm8MOlzh12F4KnHFSKsoVHikNIEUUQBYQeDKd9UkKK2jdFL5B/rLb1wRcCw8psbm4KsbqYFQ9lQp2iMPeswr8B9IarXhUmFsoiehu0cT4oC6SvUv6bcVyCiDMOmH2U4r@7d7fYR1BNes79BCalsk7OiXEo26mUqAH8upMSXoAGIgCdEqA3gjytkZKTEtJpxuRaDMPY4eGhXwjyeFETUkDmWlbFd1wlmUwmMUghy2k5nfafMj3JQ/YdMoX6T3kTkUvfHWWalquColRl6MWiWo0KCjB6vn37FlqFdqxUDkA3Zf7mFS1XokDw4GfCLWsWHLDQcmWB6@VMLeQYS9A0KFxJlhRYgm0lBb7PmRciuBJxrVSKUzzAvpzYCvYyFVQiB5wCjdWxoMHFlcVSPhkE7h2yvcPHj/efnIyaTSYY9B1VozVynY7heQkM231ynx910MqFZKzRQNAnFQ0ZjLBfyRD7O7h/dHBcYbzSfhMkqGBVWoHyq1lWhdho9Hw75u/lEPGjPY54jPfKvG4JrZyFpLG6EOsYqFEALeE//KrCY69/z5mCyp8WxbRaQDUuSRO/TPi6M2FoUo6fP4c@hTvf5e1twoBQv5Rofh6d0FoFoV73d0ExVagf759AgpNDpmoZWah/xqYyZihdCXWrZhl2fzzYxO1E4mlGjNRps5FJ45@WzcJdzRXSar7Y3NiwLiXM85Sa7RL3hV3B66WE1fgKXEz4isC@Al5wQR642Yv5O@0ODqv@dic03pLge55ENQ/dLCmcQkNzcMIoelVHQN6g1Ud@Qmzj88/HrF4HXVo6eCDEgF0MWLDlRzK78kCmdu5OXINC@4x1zU9N/ByT3DW9kaXPoO8AOmJXV1c9gHTwgGl1jV55ii7erzrk0wb31VQXYnalUnur5opCTqtU3mY1TQAPIfbiha7X641M8zJX1HL5XF7LFgr5ogZIK@cK@VI2o2YKmbymqeVcrlwqF69YAlpW16V6LatlhYq/kTubzQik4AtbihBTRVHZErLZrIDzyML/f629aEVke1QHXG8rI3Dq4MxtKzo42@DMbyttcJrgLG8rJjgn9aya2VYmdYEJ29y4GsOz2zVxbEzRliP3E@ueYfVkPEtREykDTdz2jZXW/XR1PJTi6N0aHvDFAwSJ5KXQr13QkTfBqPVlPCfu2roldGtdp0PfnhO6ctvpzmRvPLPw@IHluLU4SGPxIMDEz/niybaaAeIAzjbtZLO5SoM15ZEz2hG0fDHVUDPAx/GnltJaesPYKRYrXbljGbq7k6/kS@kunmzw14N28plKX/7s8aOH4/HoyKDjDju5MiRAIytoDmGnVMnnm42GKKYalE0Tv2vJuYS0sQE9y9C7Ejx7jj32JK3UhMRd063V4vGdrKpJaiWbKQlXIYYEwC1WsC5gyhRWLI34vfS7YcV2bOjylbSeNi8JCZVer3e1dZmavwj6pcTfAD1Xkp5uX4avVSkSr8ImacmcB4KP3gPEX/rrYBVRy5fEaqM6fy8WxGrzSrg7NLqmjoccTjOXN1MVgDVyqDHI6JQJVxXXccaVttFzXGMeMasWgoi8QDcj5MSrMLvTDOZ4eTO7AkYCHHLMATFza3d12tjXADbS3Ac@0WhuB3bwkIg1TdKyUlaV1Cz@3@LQ8P/942vwr@EdUmU14QTPgj8Bpg4Dkc0e4ZnSscNOHIc@r3jP6KyIsTfQaQfjnut43t8jzj3dPuNB901ugC0Meqjjp1W8oTkerIjxbDTEY@SG@48GYX/YhgJSL6cI9@DmWo6zLEKRPXu6opaPQ5OngAxu8xSiHx18/PAk8jzZ3917KBTYvcMn96898n6kPHu0/@AkfC3y0CBpPgTx9f1Hj66/@o/c4bOj3sRx8Sc8OHyWm99CLzwgJ@TgWowUehMQ/4avJPbgFPcGyxcDhyrgtuo7oLrd8Z35wtyZQedzfvrP9MJtvvyYZ0U4CY4E6gwZUNtgHW4tAHVJsuTjS5pqsSwII2Y7F6yYYV3HsnT8XG1vAzwHOh5vMlDcsuirypj1heNa3Quza2wIj/EkVVnFb3JiIYSHAGQ46ZDZDBip0S5cFz8ki2sqbWtisAl@rHmFJzzQC52u2R/AGHThBBGEtq4z2sjzYRekN6LXeL3HmOdBfjdCrJvRhZggig/1sR4rVe/cUZ@6YjkrevVMpdI36vtToFX2DPqO7s7Spbw4lsUHTG7F@mbDa46guQrqxmnmrJJzRnUdjZi9mqRyDZAsx71OFQa3fAXQWy/t5PYy@b/6zR//7R//KgzirFTW@jX1FHUCYHUoH5m9DVWQSfrWyqV8qZzVSulSuZTLq4V8Pq1qaVBcimWQXTNqSS2U8mU1XcqVs0B4ZQjNl4tCjO@RAzGLpC1lqwJg7Q5@LHKbBHh5AJI6X0xjrxN6ksX08H3CRAPSiALqSmM6M7pl1mCEYWqGZYsMIOqsw2IPHuxlHjwQxXv4gpsI9jKi2MWXfCmTKd4TRYNC9kooWogOT1NCszvimL9kMvf2RHHCAaDFWlEc4Mt@AWd7RNHEl73dBw8wnx6@aJgeop3xEP5iBS9FiGbjC0icBOBVCA2i7fJ8clTQfXzBLDHkAQ/ZgzBR/DgoDoYc8WgcwMOgpru7onjAX3Z3MWSPqp3nBf0EX3bpEkUXXqAPiGIfHH0Xep8otsGJPUEUO@DqzHTwww9zolFTe6yL4oyjBxEkilOKrXfORLEV@GM2n/qlySN2K/Si8lrfpZcy/omiFhQao2XDl6wo5sKXHNTt4cNP9QFQbZ9fM5c/O1DThw@zujmd7D9of/xxu99vu7Pd/Y@PMGhv7yEM8rOJ2@63/YTtFlwOpNp7qOlnw9n1C2p90GpVdGtp0CetVk63rwW1Zi0DSwipXkHJ/KuPGQ1bexC097B1V1@2sEkAW8gEhvBs43VvCM97epsHBRcF0XPabotVJH@Umemr3dAT6QPa6aHecZ0qvk9rG4zFE/H0rFHINKsUwIYgHWeqV/S57gTedZydSF7OGtNaplmb1ooa3xTTS4inUy1viumN4Y5azlc29B1Vy6WmFTyP7vTiLC6pOyyh3tl6zRJPkjsaiMfi6c6OJDbU5o6mliqF4outiSgmK3jfyRYrEDETB9Ueb8lGsblTzEeSFIspXdEqxWKyegX4GMOo3sZZg1YicWHoZ8kkFhd1WKgC/1j4jOppVnuJaXpa4@Vis2R1WlOr3I4fy9yA1UWjsZPO2HE5xD6Am@5kKvQ5clEtl0TIX1ESyWSoCCrCfB/e86@dnJ2cfCYgJ6z7uvVT/o3bqv/68cM9GdRt/w2NvcoPUDdxXHkP2dVCCLdFGnidgHQuP4RhFBSVwA/PBbmOJe9PO8YIFZwgIDDhJ/uG1@SThwtwjgfOBc8Zj1VXyXqP3TEY2sI1u0yv1cGld1mCSsX05AUN4K16vdaqDfkXxethqk8YGYqdgznweNnDw96U/BLPyvgBrVrmqtquTWNTgNOqMUl9OXS6L7VUp9pFE7j3avcwcbUFz3bVqBn4XXUxJlZ7O3aNsYnt6T3jqeGiGYODw00QJ/AATaLHjOQmO6WvsO@hDH8l1V1mz0v2ZDJMgH7fTi56RV4RNYmvBVW@pBNduFngqtqrscSLZPUVvLqbLNGV7yV3ctVu4h5rJcEn87L3ssc0VshV6duUCYQEnYhwQ183T9bqn4AExAGfVSpQEL@NzwAm5gRgzS4F6MmReVXt1CyWkNiUJQk9uWq/1sDUb/C2LYliU5Iab5pCXZKeC3Xop9VZTK95kzbZTWeZtqplCtUp@KnFXHUADau/mFbd2mjiGlULXv2JJn5wTa8COgFrAOb1m8S7X/hGclvK17hflUC9sUDoaMmt2rRqoyUmIIlatgYBqUYukwa1Fm7FNAzzWiGtFtLZdC4tFdEXxvh0Pg2eoN@ATJGwEiJjYjozzchqWjXUdCLz0uy@TKbPEiCvEMpYMj129vGj7uADjYRUSa/w1FkypW1ZDFrBYfq2RGQKnKKKFQOcD9jITA8Q1JGhW5QimZRYdithbSYwzubJZLTfaFYq@9PR1yAoIb3aKaSKmdTrZLKa2EjWPOOVUK8KdeQqVOvRBtCsPwfHvMmwAW0MLrWoVRqNNlaxmElnM1mondl6098W62IzndkoqNBEV8gSYirjHIOLSHMhZ@43aqHcbRnQdGpZqwoyTTtlS5pUVvJb@QyfcuIphZHP1hCTLHEqBoc0E/F4UYvHk/EqzpBviP6UKPAy4mNxYKrxO@qOCPKXWBHLGkaYs0Q6h5eJimBXAs4JsFxZiF0KV5dX26DUKrSREKRHtkEuSa7fFWIVxhSBnfpWX5QNxj50f2Jqu/6CP09xXzXAFchmIsiftG/IMFETY5/imeMdFoeC6e6woWnZZkMrwkgG3DGIqmlqFVcFYrhzW64Dir1LKN92qo7HdT5hs5mekoJp6juM9VObAlU6dn3lb7e22z/aDXZF7e7hxOcpiNpiNS7GLuOx@BX8CbG7dEZI42eEWCxySojPfP9c/G4sHo/jFDMg6m2MmATbuwwmpyr4CZ@EXuEsodFMvn1iWpelrMSnF4BHXV3FNhVqmuDMxScvNaCKmO0EHqAS4TQOjFb5PE7fxpSXI@9zrZR9fHBo33cfGIwfwSjlWmI9xjKqhEcaqhXfNy@2Ns5UIIqsmD1Lx9jdGG3DFsslTdS4RzXGzqS4WuHHNkbH5RfFF6UXj58dPjt8IMRON95sODhTz8JdZG/tr34NIsazOdASTmuxaS1X9feQ1euSuq2hoaUiqwC/76kFKfOmzum6TgEFDULe/cIPctPtErxrGRXeNS2f0up1dUtjydjo3Ze/h1Y1Lvc/3X3E4p4@Y3/7xz/Sin/7x/@a9mXFr6oezSsXYxATnWqhGLu8HF1eXsHFw/KxZowXKldMgpuvP6ixuqJqWdu2q6yi6PpWMZXT7tpVxY@rFtVkzJNi/kpKMR/z3vhBWqYEQcFSB3mJBWyS2P6RmdfUu9tILWp4ooyFf9uGV44JsdLjl28Yg5dOvdvvmxq5FIVV3kps@620zd7i6sJbaYO9rNVxdVrFc2jB5PsWnrfBFah4PaVsxRmoP6zeuKo2U4ym70FffGEYW/bpNVo/3WDl8jWvLRv@jC2P/jBR4OHBa/BmbH3hiYmtpKJ0u749pm2D5etAClsKlOw0@e4Xfl3TCn/7x7/ypvWm9ZkG2mG5XFC12M/Un/0MIqyxhRCodrRKgUYL0BGqhGzFt97ljijEJjbKwDx@oCCiSogShNm3QbvHN@EcpR5qpRY3ttVNULQtPCqdJhmazN8kq4IQypokI7v9TppgsC38FAd0W@FS@AoGwdDKasBSha/MQYHHEAZTp9PyrIk7opMPCUqnNtPsDiSBHL6Cdsw26Ii3z5clYGXK1s2kvMgeYY0kJDY0PA@tosGQInwFkvhmE/EL4zpaI8CYpg0DgYxRqJwU0G1A3k3I2@IJWuSboNrzCGnGS8cT2SBHC18B0YCwYILEwMxtiFAFnvMVQADUIeEDNptsm2WT7NJMpapzk2tXuN8bzdHpwUloAZMhtC6evA8SVzEeeIH8jh/qQrrwWxiEtYhnAITD4GvGNdAAMDm9oQhGpgreGxTAIrNACaoau3NnXqpazewmGdUI4Z@ZI5zDonawl5cVgAXa00fdiphmaMyuGviGZAcYT1FxgeokbsWuGknKRHy9EgT4f2@iRYq81lQUUMUK@O3Fe0UHUAaJEe28DTtsu8ZUrZhkYeE7UPYOFYoMqIUq4en0I1n7LAi8ghL@LBaYwQdGdBKdF/Tp9vpReAYj4gRtkKNBJM4M/CPs3OQRMrSDcZA6TAVVMS2K3TNdUFdoMTuwpZbIqklMNrc9R@WgXdxaDvc/a/kkPigVxmbw1NFqmJ/PBlk76TjQoN7IscnMGJlBwY3qQBHAo3wLTbzYE/sCv1nhtw0ljpbII@tMSPlYYjKbRh/7pLS4mtx2QacNcJNmRl9mnWGXaWWWIEIjS1J2CC5JiajAbZB9EcdtyxhCkY4Ng04heRVF6YPkNGmTOa3HJtDV4IEJo4rtKf53VZUL88xUTtDmtuT08LASN04QQ2ELux9fuPZNV1mOc8Ys88zg072JBdMOHgPpHwTYNGB2/gPEVnBHhJZNswwEp3ks@BXhUeTOUjqSdiMxS958ZtWNRAtb9A0NMqaL30w91@0Iful6I/gKrzfzAuMwZOIE3uWQ5Rq@WYhaHA98h/ZOBN/MTY0srMi4jDBKgPoZmIdBpzByjXOGqquAYwwwzU5gaAF7MdT2KzQAUN@DnoVW48ZuBc2DQEncbqIDXc9n8Db7iGU1ASNy2z2@nR2AgU1fW4QOYZAU6@GNu9AwMs2dI1@B3jnsQhgeTPfJD9MH1I1usug3J2@24YPDQYfyqjHeLYKXfOQFewfSM1V9AwILUMIlJdlIiCkAmxKTIgcdpr@enFO7QLykwm5CSjOE4KMaoJCoEHxUmUU@LiFAwD3d4xaIfZtyFxcXMhk6nLimbHj4wQUPvxStjPomiMuOMjaGI//TdiZ@0tSHO3dJ/Dsr@P3wnSl9ubt8Z8afgtDzav6@kkS858VxcDzH7wn0h2QUCa0ReURQD0z6Fkkn4W9z4fSnNdOXAf1VkP6kUvwKgTCGYKbpWbqTBmDpducs3bvoVv2Ac@qQABxa0Qg80bioG7wMvcBljnphDGeMfDQMaltntCQKkEQ@QTvPmtcwiDkLXv33kTmFRLZxwXZdV58lKDyJsZGAEzMSe9gMhn0KAScMM@ySW7o0p41ZcyH5NEwOg1qgDTEXLR4Jl@uBcrOnGD7l4VMIn/Lw6TzTINvGtMlFMvS6wuog1aOhvCAmgpkFca64idB5CEEGGZupHATGnC34XcGvU6PUAb75G7RjLSAMoIkRINxIKI0Xp43Tpu0ZF1vNlNIHYhcJEdDiALrRJJxedEM3Yt86t0aOt@Blo31EGJX8cqNXZ@BTA6cVrGPYQEQYHF8mmrTrD/2tBFwg8CsMEFAOg0AUDXbHCTNZDc3sUiAQTkOc45gXrOEXpknSlx/k@4G4xFHPERsF1IwAQv@wSlBMCGFBz@Gf1wm4w3PXgThBXIm@CDJE00rxZhwwea2rcF5TpUaKlEqSgmIC2lFcrV2vShAOTdG4FhSp5pXf/tHib3xw8XvQL5aXngiWDxhVIdpVcBMdiBB@dyGssnot0q5QAmVLtwwXRq59Lp/6ozVks6UEagbPB6vgXeA3gxORxu8kefvQQT3RFishKcxqNajirMa7Je8XAUo5wsNknp9sFhCCn54zEICRWZrM8JNNo8mmtRpnHGy6ItlFpJBTKuSUJ@GxpysK2fSTgfYUfmwem6cJ0inu8hMBnsqHURCDRiLDDwfjyvYXaPYNtKogzznPISrwaQhFbKSzTnNp7o1IoSNM6xoAJMQbALr8S30V4TrDU6XwLeRRHJUBj@JvPhlwXgEERiy4yk2jJkIiIx0YBH4xReMA9F0x1RBElWZ58S/Df2I68Ax@6k3PzGJMddEzk77294/i2UTMRjpoRPpQMzlkyKjJPLN9m4JRmSOGH7UdOCDVtS8cllgibIO/MvGTKm3LaStDHXeo4Pe7/G9aj2bJQH/AFRJ2d@SM9bGTy1W40mQS2S3Ln@sMZt920Ox/xDwyyHpdx/Ds@BgateP0bdMz0gwt150Zvtph@Hbghaic7DsdTxD86UmuxiJoTlco6rZa@EXRViuBW/CSlXC3L@3IQ/KMxwXUf8EVSQ/syQd6OEo47S@Mzjh5O0y05O0nOzE7Z4nDkR@IU6m7DHhYB@R/CB2ABMM8Z645kh1hFKXb4wTZvh84Q6cPUt/EkwVMfQ38wRw2FkgfjagsaaajSluJ2HOnXpLopPWkn/STD07KPtESejJMry0CWEBGmrnXcYyYdZdk11qZHU8W5Hf84eU9jpb3eH15SQu/Xmaumtd44IdlnU3MIUDEeTGytxcDqw58q3ujOAtFCb1RruIJ3ruIXdoB1sWS7kLUXT@63AP6SIdvHryFBf90Ff7XN2CQfP99m0/Hzywfz4DfDHFjYoK@1OIFS50JiH6QTAqxJdmFpH3/PfOCuPiRrAcoQoAYS4zLRhOo0DFHoHZ7oZH@APAtNI@brm7QPe3EqvHAJWVyz9PsTFvdRPdbXcPSZ0Y34cdMR@AGNT4ChY341ftVHBkdMT2H63oJGLuSYSgM44h0HqmygmT09HkyuZqseBQzpB6aKacSHqzGH4bfYM04xVfjs9WgB8TjMZyOPTdx@nM0G824lW2Lf6rD56N8/OEtidYIbkcI4IGPnmp6nm1yHfs8SoRVeo8RIYwrL1YZjeAGENHWzs02/DAU3V5TaNxIolrQysLi1yOWt7i5rsUjVBHQJF9Cej@SvI3o3pvmIqTGgc1Z2N6HDSE3IOPujE4nEYXIfda2mGPf4AnoR/N09opRpbWEoYYpidONTVK3Sb5ICqgZH8ATJ5w@hScC7BvjFieooG44p@V/@YpRyFAfRaQW3weEdIASwSJHuV@MSCwhcEP0y6swz87KPDs38uws5Bn2gMUsI5GEzkKWfitg86xrAsvojVdwZwxC3Rke69g2XLajuzhbcRk34xUzzeLn8Qow5LgRr@wngCnHu/HKfXJ48coxOc7ilU/AMe9b8TfxStAtMIILr@S4i/4@C8f3Tryyl0heCWP9zPCCfOV4JWxTiLPDXwkjgAqsN0iNuMRmO341x64BAxsJlWmGFOOlUX2ieZg0/TLwz78HQ9@SwECc49yiyCzF1IVBIzJi8Hxg2AhslS/pyRV/NN8/fEC7m8IomE0KdLxoGgIPYngsvsiMeMEwlFY04AkFRL5ZWV4iFhnJ3rM4fu5AodTIi/kT9mSSB7oJCm9A5OY8E/oIkJ8@aK9FELwB36@cmHhVOW8UJ8iOSoRrssklxUKkvoyvqRS29WJZ/NaPthDNdS9Gwu@UB1F4KxHYCE8HGY4W5zCzkTNaJBIKxX30ZjQNTcrxTonUey0ZcQW/Z64IJm@/ZsgYop0/ua46kXRYtAUWhIGNTJP3snBcIF6MQXNeF5FUeeeDIkR4DvRwo3NGH1i67zspHmc3aRorVg1DQVqeJXGuRTYJiWU07zTRxzz3UHndR6NPH6a@BimnONeSQACRlGEunL86HyC/O1x@DwTqAAnXMlgmWC8fSm@K12tH2Wslt@bZ3mxADEyz@8mlwlGYwxzloB1EJPN1tHZDxMctH1zI55mG0K9J@wHaQp3gFrxd1y04LJQS3PNFzzMNPM@01Yi6KZFY53IgtMiYkw@HVzws6bxq68vKK76siTGE5rd164Mb2F1s4GjjITyqgHsN5byXuxObdrnM@zawbe6DLFWtMM7Iabk0bOa5J7B7WroNl23B47B1dP/wyaOvw6BbLBaT/hg9m5cPey3OtYbjOIdMW6XD8WCJ2qKl8TspuNiN0/HewHHHG6e2eIOXcGYNwoAOuQTk5/fxpM/LIvz8Wt@FdDxuBKM@rLN5N9AXuBKKOjoO2aaP1zEgxBgntnQfSCDeAr7TpK0l6YsgrRZ@B77VouGr1cLNS62WP4ph0wQr4smfxTaUiefSlzP552wuBIHsGLD7h@z5w90TdvJwnz14tvcJ@/rhM/Z898kJHmF/@uzeo4M9Br/9J8f7TFjYQomf/kKFEvB63@gY@LVGpmUyOUaQ95zRjPOdxF6S@x/rQ/bQ6Ri4TLXt6cO7A/4i28a4zlPtgzo6wzlMkz71NjTHuN@Cvk0GaiwKN106@4c7@xnEbYNOO0Sdd@h0zZ4JcQXUfUem4QXHxZhlQgsCvw0OAqe5kISfIaOtQ/TxQNyBdQHJdYiPazcARuf7rxDFGIN/t6wrMx9x4fXBGDzZP3p8zNAawt7hk/sHJweHT47Zg8MjeH369YMnHwM@D45Pjg7uPcMgivj48P7Bg4O9XfLgBcjIDM0UfDHxxmuLIGN0wkrnDFe@5RE0f/i2OOuNEjy70OkUpMfiExu5j6lb5mujG68KEw/FFzx5SUsFLLG5e/TxpzDmM@MVrnAGS8G0/0B85tGn8TYzbJtyg85Sh/5WFQK7gwlJTdJ6xHDG8OsYRpXMFyTInWYB8P@nuOvdamNH8p/pp1BsEtzQ/kcCITEmMWASz5KQ4U9yc4D4GrsNPdfYvm4D9k24Z3Y/7Avsft9H2FeZd5hP@xS79auSutW2IdzJnjM5J7i7JZVKpVJJKlWV2IinFfgqtQUbFei@JcoBj2UDmip6RLAByhislBXfarOw4K0zyA2qrdnpISCl1CZGhPoFRV8bU5OSwxTTtjIACu@FWhf6oGIp@kB8Tx@WdbXDgWRQT6MPkkE9kw9YitZgO6JWdI6r4d4VxLNalQ9/uezv8LGweh592GzwLnZN4yT9xl3aUNGtYIj50OG7i0TLw/crNsJmEHCRkPPjXp9ORwaGLzfKkUyUo0S2baOcKRI2bRw1aLM3uYYVqcQNsBNqtIehypTdnDqEcZDfDeTWqPNOoysmULHpDvOeWkN4nfKGXj5Ety2xP0i/xwyIm96SeETltvWq0H9oOSq5OVVjQ9tI8o2HxgTtewhsTiHwj4AhQNnETqfJMxU7pgJMr61ZORP2iCOht/3dzk/s3Lpq@okC2mor85fgt99cTWQvsU8ydoqMHXXRb/6AlpV8lNnuDWiMs1jl@2kgBZsXvf4wkD7MJFvAJ048zVFuTGxU28@GuLo20GGyxm6va1V6Rlx8R61nxJQPqZU5Xs7OI/EVX1xKnE@TsNjdAZ3GWe/at87OPBwi3fhQv9BCmM/KofwcDxkTWX86sez4XeG@w7XyxvbmSfb3nz1ceihiQe4cNUaH@E@MibpoePA5HxssDrDu0iPNXFYVXp2htLbB09ISo9wAo33gRUD7utf1UpQm5sbT3@ExM/mdP377VpZSWUgmfQ1teJGJpZunjk2VHpc5VdoExJKdhCzJ@oz54jHMSF6/hpcMeqFEFOlCjmDfPnEVlBYhpnVnV22SLPpGTt3dEXxXbbBFRXxZMbxf7P7If8lslpc23HxsUKIscmaMiPYM5KLrWmYpPF9Ngdu@HxzJ74eDW7sXO5ke/hC07Xuh/SHcskt3w5JpyYL1cLC/3wNWJrd/CCy13bsbsEyS09AiTo@Y05tPR9a099f481Tf8dgjMJh7oUGJgFq1XXX5iNrEf85IAdcGEy@IDg63q/v7KiX7EypLcg9bhpYWg4D9SH2IrW2DLgu7XLRosoM2y@LJfElYtJl/9w3mmcS7Q1ToNYin6REJi/ha7nYwEqmnZxZeQrD1PQtEQ7kkdl@NDAqPNeBb2gMSsnGnWQ10ZjYzLZNPENpG4JpunqyNbRt@trCWuRv3XA7GNiDbJqhxDs@S2f33SdbHL009ssBCdB80uEUraZpvaJ9wQBX3KWMul@zBe7rFdCmM7GWBnTa0g@FXIbnC/nGGYkaSRbishS2xrhfHGjVZH8@bZQ4bJGIaaMDSUyeKRTMlGBHPX9btDnXjSS@TnIJokYmbD1/bXEHFT2/1FMbUiObJcrQgt8faPGNzbLA8hXZWwy7dnekxbKFXJ8XDZFUkbe@tKvv/U5XMEomaDM1nNsYkEuTVlZWn34M92QpTPPujsGUOmZSfw8s@7e9jkOE4ZPU@cW7tvWfSYwa4h3RiWm8GzERBWurMmFMSbefJyMaPcBG9ECGDaOi4THKyVleNJnCbDV1mJBs6Z5lqgzWEo4bKqJmi/u391UEgf7e@R3@8PhlsyATTwVtY5b/rDUI/9sqzIrVYn@DamvzmDwZdzib@TJeAkmE3pnud7djbTgxepVVI5PM2uyVt7Z0kZree0TVwJaxezOH@WGj3SpPqvWyxZDd1p7ZbVYscJbGd0EWmBinXkj2Pgu59CLAMZr0Epg/24XscvqT/hINnQBKZ2Jsvw7Rxv4sbU4RWzcd8G442C9WytTjZ@@2w2egiwIeXehyqlPeECrIWtrq3487SrBdKifKEXNjvZqiUl8rmUlyUvkGhC0hJENKb@G5NWPDUMJaScK8578E@Cgdb/ki0Z2w52cgX1wqrLxxuXdcbepfHL069xWY5pWjybXQvw6vBTeuX897FdVt1VP8vZ6Pm@LdflVp5pp7iutAnEqq2uFrOc3TQ5/R3Tb0oMOdqBF9x2N2TlFI5uWlQqQUV78NLj5Tcs8Gb5pfwkJjgUrV4abgQLnbD8uXx6mm5Wy6ULo@7pyU4@Q2XysOl4lIGH57QLEoyRk7mj4enmFNtravfvVa4gJYvCtSuIYpdQ@jLu8Yg6O1W3r9JaOOwAIAKTNt6s0Jd7o6dgzUbfE9yXf8mo9VkngLHOlggOXPsFVSE3zvrk6GOaQWEGfWKR6vZcMR/x64zV8hd9Yc9TjFxB8Fa6lvwzZkzbkwF1ihQluPARCeEfwHBifNkcDAkX8diRZ0tynKtCN9J1wJxjJIsDlMnqRR8CoGo9uU6PnXCnN9oXgAJXJb8jYup9XW@OplYLcyxFg@mHI0BO0wUTvGIAxD66fNpA6rglXvIbh8ONR/vRTzIF9ZRDdlPhg3kHV4pIgXm3@or@zdx@XUigBB@TtZcOa3i1CsvWkiK7yArFxC9LLnxxzED3CqlU@bQWMCW@soxcLYUZxqhWk0m@j53A3IKreifbkG2yG9TzYjyu5KdScLn1PotBC25SzlpAz@duFjGKpY1xUxmixRz36UGNF20PXrn07Aaqy2/0yGkhRZzMTnwyP69uv6lqP7wGHWeRshLenYqPZtIz0m6IBXnytEEH2d6aWdKpb/G@W5VKs7mTdVVVrx4yVFPN3O0JInzlu7LG@aGvXoQZ96IulK4MkpYTyRkrZQvM3pfUh4lykQMHqUfS7rm72Xd8xGWibyvk/Xj19Ed5LPxrLY1meDSXDfovHL0Pbs6BWyWImoqJcX5Rj5lBlVZ@2BqcUIrOOj5edhulGMoS0UjcXjMpDbWX6dyepHxKjOJhngxTg2sGWPEohLXucSEG7HDItXDyY8sEAwTjKbMyN0whce68NgCi1yPTLXiBTk1wKlpk0O8DL/Ib/hjBnsSOZMvPTtxTjAfSePFuzlJIBa6j1KzyZSUJnAXkY@6UffMInHd40mIs4XEe0sLHNXpiw92G2rwR5GcsAWFkRRTdI9SNKXjDEXDvnd1IRJvnf/NLzpvGrTG7nf8kapgm9FgLywn4eA@9MNhiEhPHK8mvOr3Ozh15AXfDbtQ65ghyys4bokhWjN7zqnBskfye3jSDulUKKf2APkGBiJxQnh1fg5nMnjA9m4gWqFxCYY5p9Idi0KDxszTZXEz99VVKKemtNs/t5GQnpPRA0qH/UbTzzm0Rgtp9eNIU9uBvsmS9enwG0EsMZrSXjrOn6@C5i9bb3Ce@7xYeFq0SHatj4MLuafPYgcrIpJJWEYcwJXiM8exzoabcjacBUBP7WKi/0i86V/73a7vVGjG4IwhLVpDf3Dtt3KOs@9Hh8CAC1bGyST8sHtXg6Yod2jR1SBmhJdw6MlxGHEYfjE/y3Fxk8/KPAeHVvFpM3X1ddACAY3HSbuH02E@sECYAKEHCl36QyLKoquSKPHZs8aF1y6XUEQRNRDnxDqbiMjQ7Q2DJvUMa7KcDoGSY5C4sm5rAhOqr9lpwDk4NwsBuMfEFDAImKOk@3Bw9KH5H8JB6YaZM/aG6Zk8Sb8ejxUa7v4gIOkbE5h7hYtZuFMHH76tHaiDvZ3DT5X9qqLnD/t7H2vb1W21@ZnPuHFQzqF11du9XZIu0Wm6nJrv0YdU5YBKpjjBqbz/rKo/fdivHhyovX1Ve/dht0bQCPx@5f1hrXrgqdr7rd2jbT59Jwjq/d6h2q29qx1StsM9j2s1xZy4nNrbUe@q@1tv6bWyWdutHX7mGndqh@9RGU71K@pDZf@wtnW0W9lXH472P@wdVBUa5mzXDrZ2K7V31e0c1U91qurH6vtDdfC2srs70dC9T@@r@4qNBKxWblYJy8ombWFRE7dzu7Zf3TpEg@KnLSIeIbjrqYMP1a0aHqo/Vak5lf3PngZ6UP3zEWWiRLVdeVd5Q41zMt@hCvXL1tF@FaGQQImDo82Dw9rh0WFVvdnb22ZaH1T3P9a2qgcl5ezuHTDBjg6qnsJlfVw1wSBqUTo9bx4d1JhutfeHNGccfYC9g0ud/IkIQ1hWqOg2ExhmEGgtEWlv/zOggg7cAZ769LZK3/dBU6ZWBVSARcXWoZ2NKiQiHtrNVO@rb3Zrb6rvt6pI3gOYT7WDqksdVjtAhhoMMj4T61ClR9xq9BPhJY/ErI7hXI@7U9V2VGX7Yw2Y69zEAQc1zS1Mtq23muY5hNq1lChBDzqDxqWtWGlPf7r2EWpyWiMzW0cTRUza2tuu0oys41al4oQjmnXWJkIp2Wk000SJ9JoIWdPyz67O60G33YOPaVRMFB@X4bmHe2lcXOpx4txzLZPWr3CBdLpe/1ip00b3oF53vYeUTKDxvRJaDX5fLle3EdcOYOcNxc/Ll0L39QShNp7og0421MMBBHIK9Z@I6Vvj0ndVPt/ydTE47wOwUR2FcmxygaMUEo3s7IjbSOIqWTPB74FmBy6YMeBzzTr0pLCM5Ey9kP50v8UvMjlYH0g6i7orn8cmltEIfvNNNVIJh0TgPzoiQdDmKnOh7/9yninY1WHPnzvv9VoZ1zVlOO@Q9oHnGfc7xc/884ni2cnyjCwfO@tQ/qHZd/MSJjp/1iRTul9yA25ZBn/qQ/5xDTYS8wFaU66KldVaaZl5IsVhkeQpHdoC7hXcyVjzvav8VPuE3Vxh@Vlp4vvb6LuMLdgLIiQtTXjHXO6Uf96eSgYaYByLg0gS6AgZ@bxVxtibRJlvKOMFMt0ELVj@0Fx94fO8TiShhexVo2PXidl4EIxs7EkOv9mvvNs82tkh0Qlsn62tPF8tOVHYrZ88@f2MejhuLEcd69M8Tus0TrJGyRYtfHikWPG6Y/ZnBs7nkREh2U2n8UfEeYjsNpKWTBBkaG6Iq3m6MNFL@aBDSnEAjkeO4deZI1MzQCbRVBetuWyMeInfoLUS84A2ZumMuddG@APY0fA3QzxqkGYgzWIcSZc4l3YXLPdSO8ZUlDc3HLgHWXIpw8cSxi2iAau62H4W3rX8pnnb6sVQTBkxXrnbuSQh8WgSC2XsKroysj9wnBGtAOboYfTlJ81v9PhZB7jjcHeNcFgZHhAZd6KS0FPHymjd6GMN@RS37CComqlpXUHL72qkeOxpdXIUGMQaDYwKrkGBjW8ScCmKIzJZJVvAvl5w1VfhVATvAJyS5lj9Tpw7qzkaSsnED9HvJiqFElhRkBOh2k1Uh2OyfI7iWBhyJsj0Q/Rg@P9EmsyAv047ToIeU8sKAvggSjJUoRVtX5kowY05aLBON2Jq2p8@x2Bu7Y65iBqmT29G4l9DJNC9MzYfPnPYw3ZmBgHA5FBs2OM3Mkm7aNDW6XXK1cVxTtJtXvYzSs8VZqqYgptdPfV42eWZsxW8uMoVXZNV4S4VVa9l43bGo562TBNbefU4TAk418T/yC@yAiQa8MylF2K1OslZBT3KjBzQoZasCacVRUyiZentnad2i8oKkZmQ/frkyxCKQG8An@l28l0hPSXmucmIizwTq0OOgofo4NgmY/LRIevO2BCz4wPO4xYrQ3CdyPAGE0RHoHOovhiayjxmQxFUElsdxnEGIW7dHJGWp9WbCHvWTIJDI@yPuhKW3hetlsmRkwAfGkPbXT6n3jXGhHLnYc0WFssvHvQ82C6iMlFL6PK4OqXZ6w1o6dhAuwlHLxi7OfVJKx38bng10PELaT4LBlojYRb9VA2WTbJ752lGIsIzamEwhLdCK8f8wU269GEhKuFJRtlVlSHmNTy6YZSOwWipqDLrcco60YTDkjIR19Wq@vZNcglBdchQnykYhNHmgm02uR6cO0TD76Y3@AVzP5ZA3ZbfiiKTWiBZFyidVOtyjMfmUJre74Ws0aCugAYkokRRFGmRoSrN0c81O2m7plQcHROxS7klf7yeiEmNtRRVFDOurp2YbzVLnQkqLevQoFGw0OLyCqMya8N1e@dmjKOFJo@tVeqkG4mUl7KIKD82S0c8idyMnj7jSSv5y49DjB76gjNuvQQFwliz4lx1Ws4xfrAp@BT4g5atE6WVTKvRh/qNtz69LvOiUR3qsH/NxjD0x7QDaOaDUZ5h1DN/6l1061u9TuM86AUN2qchqPtIJB4ex/yIDjsf9G5CvhWIE1pWptY4fpb4MhKGDe/RuWTJCs0VDv1@xjZTGA7GlQsJE8GacxgBxvdlMn/3J2OkRWWercSFnKT/KdvjFd3SnWWfFmcVlhN9ANACbmPCgkJ8SIfsmGQ5n5amMpzdl8HC8UxlVcO9w2IvgfELIhEfwyQwNshMmSXYjcDO7E6Mj1sjr8UxCAcItORv@7jYJszwZ6@BK4hJiryCpcBLVVwrWEXlFGWEOIR4GN9N7uXn/2TsCYEfQL/4dBa3zGIEFnFtE20plP2KjjJKuLB5YMAymiUxSbHgPOha7od8pcRoEmoyeXwXNdjyhxZFOszeFFdiRGZo44PL6zJ1Ejn1sYtJZUEtuBy3A0uQyjBTuJth/e/Zz/LgxyGuaM4gmLY05IyF9F2kahKVcMnrhHmtjbLEVP7@iFlefmivTRCwPMvkzLpsOJMyKxf2QAlkfsWxVm9Awjg1QT1t6rEQDnv9hQdS707ZMTMy2yxaN133u4bAwmxlmiwXW0za8hiP45Izic8E0yQpxpZmxEPYvvJzxOaTRByV6xhv5fr4O3S4i2ax3VQ0qUT93ZKxj0nxGha9ZqKJhhTjjiClpej7cZ0aXr9bgmiYsr2qs8SoQ2TUx/JogZogU0Slh1OIuU/jPkGPFlEO9baIdnb/3EnUSSM5E/LUJCWCXIKeCNwOp02SS/02jC8QJk5WuJGQihacI2/MR3nF7BmCDCNBAGJV7GdjPZRocOPOmuAjvh2gnanDWqgISURPG7aFQxT0PyIYR@XXyh1t8VAfZ4unJYE0iiDRroJz3QfJ@JvT63F9xFCmSEFDfAYpohZNyaaLh7fqR9tC@QiClOZkbelb8NAYVy0RNvTHTqqPsAaOq9IlEyMqORDqLBpoLNAu5bzjy3YVq79gIBwP6wY9jGgDIZ8z@FnSJRDOe7UQURtFRq0xsria3DLaXJXdkCIxQ8k7yK@Hoix1eeNKAHzBmMqXiwQBYU0ZexwKcOgdm/MSiOo@ooLlIoYlfeSoqLGd54x0EFVneLZi5SjMyvHChpGdCYQWFrPzxIjQmmV2lhgKTXQzcbFyPJ/dnjgHLYgN7wvFqSt0ryRpGPWcEJCvVS64sUQ5LiqvoDmYE5@tuInEiL859UXBSi1MphJ9IgyPs8XJ1LVCIjVR7fJysmiiJNHDtWtNJBIpXBvhSCr82D92TbFDnkc2odYmI7HK0PbZuPaadpm0b8v9JVTr7JRt1hgGnu0ZbrZfdbliJRGU/f4A7GqBjwwQu/2HW2ssUw0m@q4AjktnnF0ysiHkFWsKUz2ahZ2uibQXBSgwe9peW3083NlJhH09GxtDo0t/sFIoFMDEZ3bwe2NbDVVS0Msnc@fbV51Ovn/zp8HHszzLft/nKwFemh20T11CgyLM9QbncjMEcKCsyJ3VjqzY61@12/YVDDihROdRt0lOHQ1B8QQUREYvHw9ZAcQg9QT7MxqI9v2sotF305CFpoZijqGoNEyCr1Pm9IzIgw9t2GdHJ1UMDILZWDPRvOWWN75iBsHNJtxZHL7Y/RqbJ6fe@p1Oz1OfcK8wIgXM3U4W2NmxCxQkC04Y2bv3KuR4tJ7yr4OO5VeMLDavA5yZmMw9EyYuPGLj7/vn1VE/kzr@kqJphZq8hGYuIT61p1LnKVcHi38AWOFDQvtBuS8b/UyT6TSZmaZ6PYLjJ8LoadGbufdJZHFZJ6Zp9v3cIOpsdHMcrIGa7vJawMSy5@7lltyRPSJu6mRUbIOGBYGhcULMlYeVgKvZP08sXg/b7YdJRb4GQDr2D0lEuQnlxwQinwHwCNTDj@iJKNr/kqVhvTMRUEQWOLisY1ruoEAdBRzncbP8602mUqmo@f7SkqpUNukhm1WVzYraxofNTbVN75t4f1JeXlkpiczddr/Sx03z8VZtEgzWcC41Lwbb9EppZfiNwVobXTyfL897pfl6eX2jFOaPK5tw66env//rv//93/4jX9Ev/4WXTX45/hJlyuVy@fnm1/kntyW8H2@fLsyfHc/3TxfOS@Cy/@Wo4b3aMNuIzUdzgzMnLbOA9ZXtSM0@m6PP6KLKXPh32Rj8QtLlpUo3w3xafw3l5iiWsemmb3334Ud5Rlt4c@nA5FaekEgT0DHU8dQ7TR8GeDTfECUJF9iBSnk5WzGKe4SDiTJEpyppHYmH16zXPnxa4kgK8MWlGSsbdEO/Cw34Na95pXmO06DfYFjX/Jv/8i483@yN1OJJRi0W1KKnFlMp/imuvqCv7nw@gHeuZKPtQCrlUUp8tAAzQxUGvNDj/QPftTNBbseZ5yt7AMmEqeDM4gXnRbs/dpaRC9fCc2cOF2sqUZHwIROKpL/Od2@pW75SjttUwtWGFwp1vYvhyqwTlah/sQRqhGIIENd8KQR52aMqcdLHHsl4ypsvuq8dvk2IAYOs@292eNzjA81F811t85zYS@GaIzafl6@YG0viDM1oI0XqjxHgAxXZThbYk3AhveCIlbfVSm6meGHb7dPMJ7YOY39obNOl0O/KYgKx5rYJN9/Vfi3akFuOV1QqiI5XrKpSk7bfyrGKXF51hkFfuytw7RhQX6PabmUkoUcZkMCRmP0vp0cYKwpMpKiJbpHLssaq1UPTZSR0tWs6dbCbk5Mjiwj5Lxka298mxrabZy8Rww7CA4xUZMrXbgSdUEddGTCxzxuDM9wO2GjzhWpDOTdjfR6uUp3AuNeOkM4xZDY5j8czNSXdHzTOLxueSr/vHQ4a4xpNW7TyGTZzLrUQIZiABAafrnpW8wzC0iLdJUyRqClsOYTLCzpjfT2a9G0q8jlBl5qhoMOuYBAk2Ikp6X9L9NUEHWOu/gOdYKM8Jbyj00gtYlnywtJIQ0rZbjM8zKaGjmNqsMdONHBSjqAajUzDC7rQFSbaSz74JUneQYwAXXdKewFqV4TVF6gfs9O5320kJqd@xzGO/vmSknkR45mvohRrJMdcglqMb7wDVrSO/JKMAiFzkwln5MxlMnMnob7OLW3PIxzkO7LFzzdUEF1AxxeYsWeIOuoGIiwnZqj4DoycqrHlP0FodxrnhN/4pjEGK56kM68e5d3jLyfd08XMSffbyW8uY6JFspllsyqtD7ONxNJjhWbGvJd4NVZpoQk1eNJNZjjpKvFhsUhAiOQzx1/yp9/yhNBJGjfMn6SFIIkuAyb5@@vLA3x@Cs10Eot82plzF13T@ZlXRVfR3Mq/6EP54MovYWE2laymp33OoE2g2E/31ytxOQnza8uFZ8vFZ7QTOvdH2YF/hfk2G16d@SNaSoTYztLUc/JbghsShLgdhY0SfRxRO@VaE/E9CbWTkhahephzPU7EVlQmJzxB@YnKHC4VLi5ulKeBw0ds@D1FLGfyciwoMR20uC@D@TPsXaKeRgi5NukdIhwJKwOxEWEVahaQzeUrd3Goa4bLAvs55dQWYrcyEOrefNqaLbq9blYv1tzcQgmLaHjNdNYKa4XJMTo1RBMjdF4vphYeqeLGq@d/@8@9X9PD9MZy/tOAfofpX9Ora2l5pAd6e2rertMb6XVkW71Nj/O0B6bH53/7byq/8SeCg5TxOv3ZWDGwVsfpjWyZi3xLb6zSQ3F5mer9n7/@ldowLzs23MU6X/cUI1YyFNlqdJl3KV3V0ErZli7EYoUdswBDLAxpb04vMIwaLa8VWE2X1lYV176OfGXsUfQUz4ZZQzYVEk2GsaeglZEUKKOCrIA0JhRtZdluGLMNMG@Mpvr5cW41pB3Az9qcI6oyMt14HMJkaF62RdSBGamR9vPysFF4lYrMO16mjE1JySwhsbXTsnbtaen/AA)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/yb6dz)

HTA code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736971/javascript-detect-if-being-run-in-hta/5892094#5892094),
which suggests using `window.external==null` to separate HTA from HTML ([the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736971/javascript-detect-if-being-run-in-hta/5892094#comment21693977_5892094)
is incorrect, `window.external` is `undefined`, not `null` in Safari) (but note that `undefined==null` is true in JS, need to use `===`).

This check works well except when `X-UA-Compatible` is specified. If IE10 or IE11 is installed and selected via
`X-UA-Compatible` then `window.external` is `undefined` (but it is defined if used in HTML in IE10/11).
If `X-UA-Compatible` is not specified mshta uses IE7 engine (on Windows 7 or later; Windows XP always uses IE6 engine).

So the pseudocode that works in all circumstances is:

```
isHTA = window.external===null || (window.external===undefined && engine is IE10 or IE11)
```

In the polyglot:

```
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334: ... !e?77: ...
```

Answer (score 3):

## 338. [Rexx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rexx) ([Regina](http://www.rexx.org/)), 15075 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a a    z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy4iiipsddpsdoh (22)S2&:&echo 335&/ \&exit&rem ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//n&goto e nthteo18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1t@.7.8.2<auaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;ppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

























































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hatax#8;>0::&&1Pr"9?3"sge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogr61k:4op>astd[]!!tfc;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1\'ull
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD40dHw/IgjULdIigRAgG9SpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdun0pFgskQRJXJMACQIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj2@7ZzzbXk/EeCd21u0deybC3o8TjvnkH1B@bGw4Ntz/oDczDwCCEilV@RGxsbGQCBycR548efLkyTwvtHV38LOfxfBiz@zhrD@0PeYZrse6jnlmODJ7MGP3ddPNa1lBwFjbTn8yMizPrQgxpjI21K3@RO8brGcOPcNJM9cwWNsY2ucQrjG2ObEmrtGtw1uWMcs4Z/tWx@wCBObZp4ZlvjEcCMsx9tAYXo4uPdaxRyPd6rps7JiWR6F5xp7p8NKbdE6Z3nY9R@94pm1BUIGx59ZQH7W7OqPoY8fgiYoMQHVOKc1iSImxJ7bjGpCD3TFc10bPMnjqjmk/3n768bX4aoZ9rANS46ExvZa9qrIXpuF0r6fQ2KfHe3vXfbPsE8m22N5NlNQc25549r53HX6ebfcNS2eaXJa164EFIKZnDEuZUmYhCML2TAdqUfdri3V0C2oF62yDGaOxN2MSr2d9OAzr0GW6yybuRB9SPGsyahtOENH1dMczrT47N70B8wamG6aj2O5Y7xhS1xiaI9MzumxoQiK750MB0FaXnRqzc9uBqvVh2tZwBgmNjtkzMUmABwDEK@ENDA5npM@gMi0PmIDpzAU0hkYALSnEIP5Doz3pM3vijSceA9y6pqu3hwC0PWNdo6dPhl6atSEMiEn@5wPD8pkWwMkA4tjmWH0xIdSMOW/r3S7LAL8CHqcGM4FqhFaFZbPgz2wHqAaxAox8YMS/vIzGFOoGqrxnV1g@k4Hw3dAHsdWHru0js4gaBlrQJqnOEO4zx@47@gio0TWIpp/uP2Nux3bgDX4Yl7eb28B0dI9tbrL47tOHcVYPq0V22kJYRTV2AVUQCwLZmT6cAIdEa8KG@nHC1AJWWXwtXmFxIIuWYbkcy0HzLDEtD0RSM2VwQDvXsir8CkwrsZwKLSUfT2M@PUfvm0ODQ@kjlCIyuJZnGtwzOZZVSzxm3x72eLQOZVZk2RIrFFkxz4pwL7OyBrkh6BxTy3n4FeAH0MqAigq/bI4DmvM98Cny2g7r6SNzOPOhE/gOy6usCBABXxUgayWAAM9sFn9Z@BFai1cUtjcAag/0MwAvDc1TlDpGKHiwChV4KBsbCkk@FK08e3eA2QPpgGj5EitC9gWgRA5QAMpqJY0Xwh0Yw6GfZOBiEsK0mIEfYF0EGpSA8hmgYwYJWYQfvINM00B4aSCpNBA@mgr@GrizCB7iFSCsANVY8Gk10N1TyIjno3WJ8CC1AYyKlEZBpSKBAALUFMtCfRVYDpggi0yQzzLAHXApFhjIqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAs5RAUZqQI@KgKDuleh8lXASQVKqwBUzeaZECG0msVwSJuFtEAWNQdpcuCGSlML@IN0wBUqZKlCnppWnjMg4Kblobz5LHGmVoCaLUIY0E0DXDVgJQ2w1UoQjmlLQMMSMm4xnuaE0JEOUCPI6sCDQIw84ENwIS64tWKW008fjgd62/DMDk/Z7mHSAjaBApIRkmawePDMITUBlQyAwRYA6GtQ@1lsKcKVAI2Wd8VRkQeS4QU2dxRgKKRBQNkkfud8mLACEZMEibgoLUF8DYEfoYvo6CjKsGEbJJgCOKYnM8gE@k3DPsN@nqTLQjYuSaC2g906dBddw3EYxgVdwE2TrHInbdd4PcEOaY5XD4SfATKyp5vDEAFqkLpHkhSecRfymy2i3XPsEbXaEcqioW2PV8h9kHznCOiRfW7MUZ8LRn08HkL3A/4G7/0AmXOdFBTSZqK5coQgEabrDEwASFmB2DYdo0O094sOqbMg4BdRrDCtfi@LUB5E@qUsG9sgs11MY02Gwwp0GEaHZetK1zhT0If3XYt9FuIQ9GbQJ/kg2jooF4g5YRFCuqfJ1E8eBzXr2qPFonFBtR8WfWBiDzM812dQez2QUcZUH4EKxFDPsKBXHAHH8BrEmgAlD4u1z7q2FfdCKOcOaANQ6LAkpHEgTTxzZIC6aEMSrPEcIY1ikjBrz4CViVo5mfRDjsk1QsnCdUJxj1zEgzcW6De7kw5SDfM2LeIg6G9cVJYcQ@9yP8Fz2MmJDj8HOsaxrxLL6MCIR4haRHODXtUA6vsqTIcgYmdvWC7oYa7MTFRYgfP7dg@Y7dyEsoOKBEnnsDtEBCRB6DWVO7JAJEcGGp0Omck64zEDf1A8gD33MiXoy@0vTPYGAocD0MU6E8eZsekYasIcQSyvY/d6wL1vjPEAQLBRl3VmHWieUMnIPULXJknUGS8Wc/62bkAcC7W7nWdfZ30DyA49fw/VeWT5eQHGYyoCkUK3uFZg6UApLEJnPCOyAJgwRc@2ZfTv2oZLzGI7p2HTx8xco09NA9pZby6MRqjlAJdapJ11QfL4zQvhY4bC0sJgVj4XfGxY0HQ6wJXQ6KH6sE63WQ@skogugAqb3ukYY8/nE5vEmWlFFKeDPVScyFfygcnuQFi/zzavcQ1EDTknohSgIomoj319TkdZ65s@oCZYxlx355JlOLuRPcQ4u5a7@ArjLGDwSlyBw5iaBGqRJCQmHooSlI5mZ4Cy0ENpQ4oLtDZncrP44BfN3hkxqRfmjdioIHYEWQm9EI/VMCT4DW8CksdDhFVf8MCoCx53gNbd0RLIdojksBv1lRVdBqF4F9CRbdlLoAIxQ7gYZTGE6oKY8Qilhj4MmZGai7tQRyiw59Y4dmTQh47HtgMtgwudGZlkVGUR7vItmUTYVyTBkl/sWqHLiGOH72EvCAnGQ7DfqIlhSwUVVQdJAUKMWxog82yeYwRhavUEy8fvnEQ/ZyboSy3LQC1Xd2YcCBQPumfIaMZMxwExeIadBO@Dgs5EJj6FPgFsLpSsSA5q99czl5GjdyZtc3rdnOmgp/yFK5zpDuuhJeOA0gGNKBHvufFklfwpZSRIVOyxp1BSfhchIkWSocoTPTCOoJPYA0FzNLM6CXGhiYlpJk68XklMggMTch2NfVUfe9ex@wL8kGlGp9Cu6a3K@tB9SxLcJfQjTDBAkTFAd0DPgEYIKnu53G3r7BKkB5jl0x1KjcolPVU5F@ZlWN0wL58QiEu0vDLPwnU65JAivRqWAKNTyamTWCDge1KCEorgoSh@34oepO3xMNJruOfEooELluCqSJJdhEo@dAAJQsYE5cPsmF7LV1fu3QsUl7VaDZgNtCkQm91k1DwIRnhkkNQQWSZtxM9E9uwjD9tGIgnlxchXHBtQm4BTa3V24Q0caHH0fiVAJCCrYCEnB4T16/mpeTrpXq9oCz0xkoitDpQms@OJVQE6f94aardRNb5AVTAh4khVZF5MT6BvMC/5YoWKfjTHcFH9rfmoRGo4gRj4vLqURDyp7zdn6J1ZZ@irBNwFjZ1Lozagf@qPCISCKO3rBEGjvdFSORBsDhwOe7Z9/Kjmt0UeqLRNq7LgMbQ7@pC81zG6GKR9vP/gcPvw660lMIZmu3LdQzFzpQJ2tZOp1LcmSk7WKutRGHPAD1u3w8aEi3FEwQ9mkj2NqEqzDnQu04CcB4efXCcJaEJIDsoB3Pi7ptLwOKB0CW3dHVzrhFk/lYIswyRBXCbtswBm6EDUMVwP8Hk2efMGK@86UmPfHzEbTnQOIPBU9q0gnYyB1xSwIKjd4z0ipQUt1LRwZHbuisYM8PkYtebryJAqHWGZjw/2dg9rBNYfpJAoiuJ6oEvpTlcGnh9OuoawLA6IP3B1WEqeI476NOG6lMCdzgKB53XLVsAHAGjryDaThqOgaO4AcN@5XjbylTohB9A7QbiuV0b1oc6HIhrBA7u4Dpq8y3pRCph3VqHX0h4rDF3stjr5vFHMlaPdVmeeZzcKlEZXoR8I9EYHgk5dCX3kuRbpq9U@@kePbyDukhIJpoAUYOYOmUx5uUMBrRfJZHFX2QELzR4a8guSeCITk4oSDwZY5Y5Lxmck/u7U9BKZJH@qSYgLuW9v72sPg8j@2B@NZJDRgLY49kxODydEOi7wiGUP7b7NNiAN1w6DDEFtWlnM7b5t3aghHT2xqDGcUwH5iwM3@hj6GvMNGY6UKmqu8tkZ3XLPQUqrhSwSiShEoBSKL3@hn@lArnm5j/Y/34VORM1nMqE7QxeQIJKGyIWuTsSXPJgEGck@PksLGM6v3GjtQYAUmeDAQvuCLky4PQ9e6kkSU1aWxl@K0lftGxT/wp5dYy3w4awFjgjJ9p8@e7z/dPfJ9mcnnpbPL7znMuUCEA7ya4MuJA843bC1bvCmicVCcDFoGw42L5ACEzBQgmH3ieuA4JYxiswRWME1fGYq8VV7YMXd5PXCnGOo9IXV4Sz0BBsfj@onBEO7O0RjxOHTe9ifI/8MPG/sVhQFWvlg0pbBaFW@6NhDva9QOugYhkNFRdNl/wDHNdxlKQAZd2bwFHxwC1SHGY0g6sORDcYLTRKiaGAJDp5GrYZmfwC2MM4kGk5SDjmYSqN0wUIAW1kJy0YCmN6Atv4zqCeRs/ZXVK3E@VrNaDlFDKItNH@Iu9YzwHRKQG8FpEhee2Un907usRlIaYR0HUiMyRs0yOEy7AuGDBRJGjVFOz8gDkkLHC9FWUE0ej3B0VyQUko@kyuqhbwCZhmYaaCzSjjmJo10rzOQPFsCeJLdo3GDCBf23I5u9eQN3xEgC3rfR1DUbOPlyYnVBAX95B7hhhN4jVmzoTaTVXYzyYYfP1kF7l0oHvJu4AG8S05gTXqyFfKsq98UZ12dWleXKd5o7Pc50pg92QZF6o0N8rprRNseJlCigcrGQlwFI79VlgwIDTGpgDeklAINCnpaYD0F8ZJA6UX1EDgH5FYkAZuPZvBy8AnxiBxBoxv53rTjLo34o16Do6XuGIhIg80dlNIujg960DuGnI9SGioXhTQ7N@I4jq67fLQSEvmTpUF6sNVCCDQqH45IW@E0MDABpSLzHCQH8BUOmw7mo4xo9AOnQYaEEw4@gAZh0exBH@QMJOYF2eYF4TmRz2KRTi373EJobYOVpLbp8cF@e@LgpKHZjZYNomc1HgegUeEicp1mF9tGh4@y8sRUCjACdTYyRjYOJYB2RaLAoCLofGYSbUEXR6yhWWUknH4B@BK7vwNSrGPw8SJphEYUsNQui3uOsi19rujSG@DmW3QrLPx2dGqdKv04IMDiPDGNkvgjoKSd2COK9ILGWzDwQaDuCuOZN4ASA4eJes0eG9Z1m49bhIlkleZz43EQ@KaVuIivra3FK/F6PA2uLXBtomsLXSlwbZFLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/ZvyqEUCeJpvIA1PUHN6Y44TeqFSyzbTeUP2nhs8kVAVQHmJL@AA48WSths5kUqyf45wN6O@Rsu8g7xx1HHPsk@CroBDwd58GWSICmPeozTtGFW3T2ykyqjlgNBqoYiac@Ekjc9I8uTjppk6u4mlMnazqNbAPQXh5iZHcd@zJGBS3Rq4igWxLNrKVZrVdi2fiG4lESRpCRnoy@VEpmdI5rRNxA3gqcXISB5L61Gl0Bg7Bm6a1ZDIkFODRM8HKGA4TcfmiBPm3k81kKg5pk/E0iOVaPA506SARXCo0jghwJtozp0BKaJjQxUXnFEhA0uQUNtfPjfFg5kQjhKNuoGXjCPp80h/XRqAUj0rJNzx9VKFbsPQDvZfHA@UWB@9QXxrPuHQXOKYnysKSlaDfPZN6I9vTlU9lMJrkSHcZX4srkgQ9IYVwSFTsJ6aLTVi3DHviRkcalw6AYu7gezyYgLAM1vOkgavMsWB0BjaLr98H6Cyc78GuBKeuJD4BFgDodmT4oRBFrQQnS0C7oJUZJshFWtNCozIqIcFFTzA2ny@MX8thblVKwzKYkdm3bMeQgCSQQqBlKLSISagzfyXMPo183ZiX8EOpS0PD2zRAIu4NbZ1oy8V1ZD5oPIqkB/sckhwaXWEI8qMH4lHmdeEYXWVDoFla2xlADwGlQUmshbU18gMU2x13ZW8KSYUEdrjRQG7dgdJ5zrqaphU6@V4lCEOuAGIPoJLQKrXAxA2CJBUCk34l7/JhocBGf3rwcJePnVBni90rjqO1RnZ3AnqlbzcdGlY/zXaBn0zLHplAhiD9m9PhoW173MqHl1UjM9xoNkeToU5jPteHZW5N17Hb9pCGgm5LOo8/cVx9qPNBqCB0@9MnoOs/Pz6qyZVIJEU/G92aN45DLs@W03M/OudI863B9JDLGVNcz4vYbwXL5FDM@AEFDJj4i@SgjgL/IvoHTQrnUHz/EvqPcIEc6Mr@KAK9hp5@xDJFxEVzuHLI97xQM1fov9IGC@OpFI8rjnNsL1SN/M@8Xm/BO0vepxKKpuHcO0fefPHcgo0YRSnPI@FKuoU4UUAFihMuqLsezxde4VqDgTEMZhAPQTHBWTLo24eoPoFtgpo4X/NmgCI9xskQktA4xcY6oGu6N4YtoE2NJR5biK1RO4E@TEHNRVhXmD/EXaWWYtn@1KTLpacNpj2NnmzW@WQ2mk4Ot9oUPvi@3gIQm/VqsEBpVTTMKR4PoxFUwg1SUDFp/v5GUcPVGC6NqQuUpCq4ClgNUy0jnUyLu83LuOISGXpMPDmZfpTRPgPzA1eXrd9T@kYVM1xFr2oQEvdV1faMSaDYYSw@Pt0ZgDhhqekiKaF@JlbPHnYlPhkGfMG4GYUV5K9FCFe9@YsbDdMJFrzRikOeFMVoZK3cDbjXqrR@M0JkdV0ICFrJBbs8TZ9dsgb0bGeyOx6aXpNdyZ7dGiBJvIljXV@Hx1VNx9FnruAvZamx7cOPP21kmhyCMNJxgqvEa3EaLOcE/Rj0IVxfCy5ckOOZHnX4tODAxPKqMiA1pbkQQB9g8AyqLMzILxGifmlczsvSM8AgTRiIuTsbpZmRvJJ7Q93zDIvzHJ9lXE1uPh3kZ1Oj7Lf8uYUKy9AEDCigJoYBilV2dPxw9/BQBs51E/FdnKipQHPUOwPQQ1YVOqBktPAV9lE3zj7CNEm0zgVoamBktPz0wNRVYHowMyB3FBF9w0mAZxLnWDrgTdNalJArYj6BcFlVxyMahcASRhLKRMAqS/F/bnGLysezAhyfIkoCuRP3KkBbMylPLPO17EJ/QuopRIlzmxS6hdp6goTaupok7nHMEc4QgyFFuiGUoNFg0hsQehBZZM1mlU/1Q1y0s5w@UlcUqSpo1W9NDaq@Bt6guRAEP3ntLXvZyEjlZmp9GShaQ@Yv2OXlj8BFCIugXWNptusJau83GjLHgU/5cUH@nKzma6vSK2ydO0Q@tEzRg3VRJHRoGdXicqjFxVbQyFCU0IgLFiQQCTF/ObXPsxROkh9MG0xGHokkuwiJriHJ2eUl0ZCta4xoCC6V8cq4CoxMEEyPbSjNY38pdVQJoNbqrxfBNnsiiIE1tTghiyFcU1fOrimh0pkYTceVQNM6tWlaJ3S1MrKaR8UvTD06Hd5M2TPdAd0WooY48LjaKuzcUbtHtyURaHbDnzcnDxo391Ve0BV15ZAeNIS@JOfFtSIL2baN3sTq0yQjupn0@o6YUrlEkXvttrkqKhABl38FzyXRQEghP2tyTlaDtdk44gL9EQgubqTMi359mRFboDv0Dh6k8p//9RtdoP/N2hlAR4EDjKGjBV031pTUW1lZflJ8odvyiuXj4JOhqRNhyHUXyI7uQJH0YehYDprm2iUJuv8Rzhz4NQ68iTdQDm9hM445n/gLnsszWTZ3ZoHI7KyKe23ZFc@KZnnAfusSEbgSZBqUiEQXrwRjymdaIpY0irG7kQrWRjFiZl7vg4k34XfQT@@sRHOMv9vaph8zk9fbqgEWot42jVuq3NFPJ11bGp/2Qz21sCTuvPQ01SuBOuDP@rbQubz4vICO2Yd@Nniuijbv2pRzetzFFa41ccdSm4ztLn@jhjC6JQdnyO@ropj@pqbQsZpq5pBu78mJPnRgFH/Rg4JLSqUI0cxrZB7q7RnqIIMP57JwAQFInFonlcpkV8wgj8er06PBSOnL5eWpp3KH02PZUIDCl61KfLCMCuwvZL2jVqG7Mkf6UNK6EedKYb5s/cGNqOHUJaUxznDi5mxpzc2pjx1SZzLUnbnrFhaf4xHMFqwaePa7jWdmxwZ1YMzUoqxqQdcR6TBIZAYr4OYZ4aphukVWOZjLyNgFsxA7cSl0LRcBdsfDlaEreOo9BBpfkYnrXiNMIturKNWxz/G3Un0YgGnK78t7tDdLsXoP4SQNO0Md@vGV3cHCGCCOMd7BqOema9BtOWFPlyLqdYZL/RebQDC6Fx2tu4utXXNou@yI7rcRqO8AFfh9OUNHaWnqlkRj3lH3LTIoWMowr1B92LeHhVJf0eG2stYnTg/lvv98XwkXSihVvUNCBeqPban@c6VcP1Wc07sqiDZ4ObiMNeK8pYtdJqb8KZbVpQPDAOfnlpdsL1OilLLCR/RWZIwzK@f6LHj@HbqOVaQNuo7xjNRp0O4wQbkEDs/hKvbfJbfc7bl1308o3QBbvKsQkco9HRrQWdH9RpUyLaN@YAo1k3l/EdUbToyJsdTQOGh/YeB241uMjPdHKuMXY90fkMc5ANyBEsZ641uG74U19tP4dqsw0Ydmx7hblVkUamPQvsdoOj8DxzN03EzRtybjhVpdsM6sw9tJNhgHTdruLmCHIR8qh0p3aEoL@rlr0O9Wi4lbeLgOrJbLZDK@AhOZWFl4uc2SyoZpvzD5fSFj8pnnPI@Lk2lOxLk8DyJLdKXhShGkrTLsKXK5rFimZXgzvL@nNG3b9vBDagqEatdEVQw0S1pRe1uN3VB3/L0ibD504eKAR7u3atCC9za@bQn0QaP5tkqPzvy8V21KOLc5wnmnxdfbh28i80h35YL7tHFMiK@xHa7WJf3REFUuycVbWx3XUO22MdT5Y1rI3QavLGdvhbcoNPw5WZzD5TO38xn32DWhNJ4BscwuWCkDY2TQ6y1avt7FIwX8x8pIUxt/q4KnhtFRprtGZ1WEsQlywcL7wlRxRFnybAvsKw@X86GdMsQFo77vKgkcTO4tJfL@SO8b/CyL2yTlfMACF81ws27uXD50UeELZTqQbH54wWqWgEZ1aszc4LkU4JNZB@p1Mrp7uO1a4@/gGOh7tPZVK1VvdrHWwB5YA2PAl4eHb6saB/Cjx88euQ11wLo/wBVr4/HCSvYoPYf2cPg@9ETRyAWlbfeW4rSLe1xxg9YHwZ3pbQjwH3cO3ukelx3oWNlqBsYE@iXX9uyxIdHbqqhDHOjh91UyNJiL/ruOIN1q5wNFguffFf6dtmVft73xmB6t8XDi0o2SSrQ1@S69qcdXoNDaR9vpy2/sUVv2PWV/eQpNgS8XMW3T6wxwbzjnbKNvtzsD8y6k24buWeapEgz58Nf3sl2RMiaTHqK3PDSBvM5MRn6pRcOP8LG/qtL90SPerYWOW/SVZSN0tPtaGuunHZePhqKLVXBAONIa@R7tCu1yr7yemN4caGTJUji8y6cl0LEKd3@RxErNirZCzMWwv3hiJZeSko4KuWRkQOFRV2W7uJwt0sSyWX5bhVC0lIRRZPnJh5DbX@JDo4NmZNwW/Bf4a2Ft0tJOzhpM@u5NgcmH67ugouFt9bAFLVmODFlDn6Vb/mMVmbWhgnsZ4dkCnWti3Dqnkr91UoXiqUNJt014tOABVTdZOYY2NMcuvzOpt3Iqzl@yBLb49flCTpvZcmPar5iu0eNTIOi6S0Uc2Q4uOAYdROrgTDqOoKMw54oXF1yW3QehLg3ZPHIQd5XasnQ10PLqD/tM6bOnRl/HJdWPTQ/XZC7hCmLZZauI7oT9tYnuml@bQMlWMRsezMCnIZ3oDn58WwLvid43O48WKiJE0iewv6CTPxbYH71u1sX5wHRxRVPouGVgClmOMzFyXQvshiUxr4/bh2dSzBsQ3@24NPaysXV7PMNNYTNy3Tasbno0yuo/V5mOq9Z63YrE@WQ0nrj@YzkOtGYqOgo9OiV/99wE4NJrEK1soA@95SPVkSFX0ML8TnHuXKWNf24O7T77vJRhoLSBEobK@RLGeQDd8zNckONYSziR8n7PaU8c6JAcXrDXULdGlkmmZXq3j@Z4Hi7OCZ5YGN5z4EYE5THe5fsfCkE6Xk6Rx3fr@vMdyHf078B5R/bE6RjoDI8ViZoFfq7GTrDIGDdu2HgsynnUSuvYQ2he4BgubTId25p4kjOxbu0VCrf2ChU2LRUibMASX9t98jwZ5QZalH2XFmqA8Tdxh7O5a@WCgWtMZlqgiK2Wo4uxA1viIT8O6ZBWBN@RZhvPbOqQuH5oL7N3ns2gA3lvgwmE/2T00OjgtOGdeT@1n9iWDb3RGATl6NDgW/sXFnosT4jJHuPmdaBP985sjgjsik6Iaxv62GhD/Q7nrvfpizjgh7qnr@iKaGyQ7L/QdSevmMO24XxBg34R9yqTdhGhR8aUbIvVDMPboOR1OlwlxvG4hTayMGPjjm3b4neSthl4qE9ulyrQFdDt/SfKZVxvvzAusNQ@WyzqwRlfJWJ0@dkTq8rqGG17yO@3rEmyTL4mQHdMw1Ue41EG5FfIMQm0L/dWGVK8VYbMTSPQZM90lybpl5sac5Dq9AOWAA10p2PjTJjvuGV1TuT8gTvEdLiEny8caAPhpyCx9M7EP1zxLrSGo/aIbisNhkhtHhpt3PzTpkM7PH16szL5yJB/YkFkRVe4zz8QV9ioCyzxDKyR5N3d1oIdtUhVc0w3ktQrp8tpsY5kmUbnjY6jZjbRaz42vRAOZVaeknPFWHWkGdEosqLThvalLWlx6RooNEND8gYO2PyKd9vwdnCaypL5kMnIwEnmxVmYlaqr7Q6osPby@fRQuDqG5B/pB7IkPN6P64fS9krNE8HD/8GDryrQCbcKueCEERBdd8/gA/ITx/If78OBz2zX65nTA8AbdwGsEidYrDwkgQdvGejaWFUIqD1rMuSjD/3IuqtRl8wxiU6tlaQhiWvPkAzrTKLz3qY3S2TzvV3KNp526hldyT/uAGcapMfBNq8wmv9cMoEalY242FNVOGGnhZy//HMZcc8DyQD6lu1JY5eeyth9tv/44Fgeu@rS/ml7gLsjbuhxC@cnaKVMZEjqC92JzHfy5Whd0/WUB0eqtPN4X8YIK@jNZzQkeODM3MJj5binf5yorugrrSAMNbzlCuKj4yePU/OdmCyxM3DskZGMBu8cHaVxp8lXj5YGR1PvQevo2dOVyfd3VTW5hH2fWzQ7uEp6LslpFaRjA6xRYMZH/PiVO5Wrjj02usezsfEpdJ4owd33zL6wspBP9TOzj62QlVcSihoqK8uFXDKyMhuMbcMJn6vq89Qco7Ts0EPhj5XLUVBzyCpOdrn2cNuM/3UthmX8lQgflkjN3ORWz5SgZfQH6FJ09@@LmKqqq@h8pPegXll@ZWUtRlg2Pzy0z95jKtnwjRcp9JI84CrJvHMdeVEagehW8IbD874nONsrl8HcBiD0Lixt8OeGNdMtieayblMvKpAaF7XdGuVz4z0mpMIVPmd4wPPSOb5wST1LdMiZvCPjYyeSZGfnwf5dCQ59Wt4e6@Onz9kz3cWzRm6PGMXYeA@M55rRFxKOW@FBdyunU7sOgNJuhdcfL2/PFXakO13bmk3vnoSjrabYtdMZwiEsfKNIxtCcmsv6qg4f13q2fJnRXXnzTRz2bEEPjp5B4wN69@1/oaqZDJ0whE81w1/vqJmggbMEuvQZHlsXDTreD0VDB/UWGTySS63Rx8YUl6Pw0eBlRv3S/q1wS99XTK7uTm4LK90Slrslvxth6Mmycka9BWD@ljCWl8Pgx/bwfGDLO7pjuEvWHy9F6LaClG8pSDkind@UMjgIShOLvnu1io9bF/zHUm49NjwnNx7YbTO3tAzbPTxLkj3BM9FvhvvLKXSHlrf0bX/LB39fnt/5xFia0RP9zfIAkjSnS4NACBqDCW2JuBm8OEHaBp3XsPomP0aRPbC9XXpbiuQzG1esL83yoTl@OBmvRhREIp7ef12KL0R8Aaayfe6yB7gjbq6dLzH5cVnccv9VqiwLxwPxENFHx9sBUx0cKVokxzkWnz1b8MY9o97BUcTPMabTm/nxnXmHEyt6eLOb9o/f4DtZ@f5BVw5O2E4krFQqmVz8LkR0MyQecZpYxyP@1mnjI8S9vGRr/mZDCBCD7Yv@9ko8CQyMHwP3RwoEwqutQza1mpovsy38GEMFVJsk5YhedN5SkFeDrV/4OwcrFfWKrdWYWBGZv3czPD6VHwEKcPHwQigTk05Vtu5ByHqw75DRafbskpG5BPqZms/Am6xEd2BX/Z2ZgNL6xbP9Z7tHx9vHz48ameaVv3MzKIRlQW7B/vCPsl0Ryu6TDcQwPxCYdgwPITs6aR/NLDcoF4OSXStabaFo80KJW5hm/cKyFIU2ryrSFeAniTw3CgWdCr047KDEVD/@vuUK30dK22GhijhokfKEOquwzLKMxzqIlHXLD7/@1RAKxa/KVPC7Mpixf4YrNKi@bXf9HF2D3X0FOe5t7z9@frjLAgTnTHNudr1BrZznR/zyDfVQTz2TVvPUWNxPEoe6qtXie3EgTFyOswptN6bjdYHPIVpAHdyo7KfeYIl1gg8UjIeVovzXbyhXcRkXpiYhbjxAKg7ZAssTo6ytrbFjYBL28HD/091DhvjvPiRvJBGCYMe41/FPf9zlB9QHR44EX9RxRiQI6GgHIbrfOdgEPN@njDSnpjte/V0dOhCedgOHJ9GHn9IQBPpQAfDtOZ0Wdu0kqSQd7sK/A@Qf9BVkRCwUHGqNY6B4aJfjsjPTNXEvMuLQwzO0Fpkdl03QuXEy28aPBuGniXT6WgKgPrE8fk6Nf6pFDDhNDkVOmq0TsvzbCmIkYnxzDZi9bUDXwFwLDEvDq7AvgBNxnLHC96pLUj1@I0kAukIuaeCNhpGINw7dcpUTR3n3K/9M6VcZuD1wf8d3TzMP4O2X/LceuH@Zu18qyGg3D@ma4xJFCA/W80vAEQnpj7SPfCvJ4ucDzAmHZ4kFcpWZI6imM6I6Ruc58LsE4ngOJ9H4FCoN2A1qzD8XgOdnOM0EnuxXURRkKVRXZFqVbUz5EqlrJ/wV8oWcqgCS0lkAkI7k7uPeTw4wmaxAMxHOzHHtFfSFm5ubTESbxagVqrxmlXXrZVZ8FSK6DnGF8wEi12CQBpLMU0BY3U8GnU9KTWJSlF5xNY6Cq2tDr0Th2Hvhu@UTQmQJIBankYFnPE/xs1qeMwtOqmzjh6gin2tY9wFJKvRJ5EqKgr@j/qntAftAI51/kIXvqMclgrwHxCPgXP5ROTogEvlRvtmy5htBg@9C@G1NRhnAQWUz1zvTaN2KLxDEEYKoiMvYt/GSnXgnVlPhvMmATX@4hJktcP@i0l/Bs7zc2zePB0xcP9wPicXuH1k2Gmd7UBiW0BQtq6iF5LxIudzSIvkl8rOB4uDhJJeQHYgpEBkdw/zCHrvbO7v7Xz14dnTjCDyKGb8eDeR@fTN1IsnpRjN0xKPFWqySB3vK0ZMHe0FFzJEuRKQxCH6/JOptJZmPuSDI@Rr@60VbhuH10q3G@AXf5Xsd36x2G2qU6AYeauYD8qV1tNIe7Ya5nrlWWkatfP42lObwlAjoHb6V8QaqieTFVaO5WT@xYvGbnLCkIbyMyRvYCMB14m6sK8jsNwuHBQs/93iM34Vyo20xu7wtiutZPIkJd1J79un8DCrfIxIQKW@QDYhIQVaCqCtb3wHX0ecnpWn8c5T8zKboiTQRhAuZ2ygeAXUcfNkSpcj8nEf/iMOB7g6GZlsITgLiRx0GJ7KFpxzyU3wSScH/WgDPOOF/63Jamcq0aCaRRGlHsNLstlMTA3hJARo0anfPJmB@PbPH/PRomhx9aASuQxvEL9h8ZFUZ7KuTEcTr0ePQoIFqkNwSJAZKxkNUuS4FUsI/NHGawmMpIb8GHp3oF1wedfOJaVIeGNOu2QfZnkimQaJ9pKpNFh6siIWmgxStuEh1Nq@FW5vix7hBNUr2DzpdczpHQG/oMtiKxjQRP48nK03IH/3j5y/O4klxGS/RKZ/@sZfd68d9hugX1dslie75rTM4S3OZtCiXb0oJ8LsOmJ9HFXy6plyWB65AnyKroeZ@5DmPwQlqRKI30scsMbH4WV4yo9fEScJK0yFHUp0fB2ixVIoMKnhQgMwoZY9cvP9O6NaMJZQaMAH6ulYXH2/MMWuostwEN2WSZOv4Sakd0LjwELukADYwJKkQ2BqyEJgZgBFvJDJncEiD4RAXHnQi2pJg@sIOjefZSBMqNavfY5FPhC1qjmK5XPErdFEqlhlw301xKCsA9oacC/R6oK5/zAfQDMxfWYjNBflNiRejfGMckUf@@SCATixyhGdwbAgDWPMDNjsDB3@JXQvaCugHlcrz471WKamILDxnpO@YXRxv5qdQhyae/90QaKbKQtR4lVt0H2MyPNGtxQ8ywYPF9qjBiNdEaixKhutf8J3zpqreyvV@Qr8WIGYOOwB/P1YrAIdHFwYz/0vClgv7n/0MvxEsJtZV9bTlnKXi@UwVbmo1z/Lso/UTSVpvZGr313WworzX0xOwyZWN3MMzY9Br7/eVE1FkWZZTlI343sYzUyu8fD29yqql16djtdCQX0@bYqmWPm2yZ88@e9t6mxSnZ7PX4kmCTpViOweXoppDMz9WKbOLrUI2dlrGj0HSH1xvyFI/ZW/gOu0x/Cf3m27EraO73cO4YlxksZMT/PavWBQVpRFvwj8BeQUXN/wbdbkubzXfvk02dN2bznKmaY7dbhd@9gA0SC15pN2r3CNSZ7P5ewo7uYdHmt4D0c@a/GPQMX6lUgmJ@R5Sg/tVR9Me@U23jX5/sqvPuL8Zm@Bjz/PTPvn8xYsX6HhBF3tzGPNhc4hBHpWWno8xLaP96U/WrtIXz1qbf/rNkWKs4eMAH9@5eoLuIzX/0draRw8e5HJpTdO4@9nnz76@vb2de5jOP2vkt3JSZm3zT/54bU3TNjVlrem6ajPeOD39TNQyOVH@0x/FW8@efc1169n/4xtv6yreinA7Y0WQE3BlmQpOvJfgp6KOxciuvPuKvYkBl6uxGf21YmHAGlPrW8X/9r2D1zEvVteUFw48vdjrWKEU405wwFs2eDuL1WObGK1wFZsptVoNnMX/9u8hff2rAAdDZptwq@cDWIVZrC7VKMllrF4Ah6ppkO//9Y1vRDDkYqJGalxw3WcNuMRcURO3mnBt0LUp4PltUkZRrHt9G/oxsOe8gWfYaumeeg/dpmHjwzLwvGvDO4nhx1XZwX3GDhupVKoptyS45Jdku6uqdgICgC2wFo29EJX8V@7Don4hn/g@EPYiRjwFTEV8xd2@B7Ea93hxPd6LJVf1xT/2dSjECmv3Xz2s10EUZuvZjXqKLnYSVIDCiiXRtu@LLM1excFUaTRfPWb8@M26mClpYjqdvt/C1ymSVJrG5gRknEYstkDZGJu/sahXjAXJ2DzOh8bbxevP/tc/@/6ffY/@vk@//4QH4Vlds6dsQLozaDp1uO5XKp16Xaw74sUJvteB3zKVUqWktK5OEhsgqZqHTM18fBnPZ@NHjJoc8MlJMhgPjYVXvY43@vffyEXPa35@SD18oRjzJHfHo3yhC/aXDEqNs3pTQsWpJjXUQr4pcX6kMuJVZo37UE2iViyLzbqW1w6g6lSRV9xg3WV2DCzIAiTagmsN/ugfrvB1Dcec18hvLQihWDevtTDfOy@AWVE3tKyS/6iwqwmxRkNpGk1QZKF79aPcX6uslSqFiqa0boHLqje9DMN45sbOVLXTbrffdNo6XG29o6vefbkol2RtU5/oU32me@1Je9r2OpOOqgqxt401dsibQZOlguskdef1XJZbvpMcNv4kyZ7GhNg/wlVXNZVtgCDNwA20B3KCcYd/UA4Wu4Cr@Xaj8XYDOKSe2qTm2axLPpbwkFv3mynp6qoB7mrV/9@sh84qXdwFhWtepVKbL@uS1HhZb6QA5EsfpMxhyq16c5MCwrz8zPzgeM6OF@z7m00G2aY2G5s1e4d@kBIuqQlwNxdwvX8/JYPrPgCor4MikUyl1iVpDWV4w5dVELlZTwWFQhwS0CluAgNcbV7VrxqbV1ebm/C/Sfcr/wm@V5s3/ukxv1bEmYc3WSOrlQCvev2kodRPlBOf@ZrwLit19JGVE3DU4QnxoDMTYtA8jYoQ22AbMTwoKxvbEGKv3n35P@Pv5N2Xv4c9PYM/IaZsoIFQ5nYC3Bh7YrEn/LIs@Idf8Io@6PGkjp4Wv1k4h6Aor2RW4cO0CbVUSMooC1t2r4WbbmX2CqIyFBBM1EoFsZVSZxqLbYqFIomIn79xxePxf/JKKxfj3J7GnaKvXNd9EsFsjhtErmoZVVIv6/wwZH48/c8vu/7Jz6@6hNhlGajGQOq5jFNDiEEVxCSpLsTqmyNcSYgD2hLaDme1z6Tn2xIau7pH0xUdbsjV9ndr5XKdj8WvPyOe2Xi4AXcV/nfXoBQCdi1C7AJv7df49/gN/rHjDv4dvsY/dvwG/w49/GNP2vh3/Br/ttv4dzzCvwev8e@Jh3/P@/h38nPZrFoV1y@IFCm1rF6tT0UiSTW2VT/5OV5JvfhPv/vNb8ZrtbgUpxPycyrY/WqyCsR03Xj1flyI1di6uq5mhplORm2rbXCYLOOwzCAzULvQT7VUljFYZpaZsczIVrvgMuAvAy4z02OZPstYGQsiQii4vFbGQ1cPHn346wEgB/5MXOfSVjMdBhkNUYWkT2sheHBdtk6EBtjC4isD9HtZlTNywWziBwka4qtXJ8pGUyuXmIwcIrcar07iTTy6VivnWHtmrJ28YjEXDIRqTDk5UfhQB5SVyHF11WrtPn3YaikoPU@e2Afz/4ODUfT11v/Rgf3kwB7Z8H9wcPAEml49dT8FguX@/RoIGv@xFatXt04qJK4CkRVTNrdO6lkJ3YUUSCEN/VIfeM0hwrO@diLEzxOo252jeld9cV49q5L7PHgFR6s6jxBE4w7/Cdc5SOZAjTuH6@wcHfSGzvMXJ6GLO5QX5ydo54BVFf4rysLrP8C/@f@u/yfPWZIlGs1k4uJqM0FXEv@SyYuriyv/Xk8mEv5LYhP@0APeMcnFVR2dFOkCXI1Espm8uuJ@cE8kNznAOmSzWae083ggQ2JhlpQtvyX@YZ@QtX@dxKtMny9SODmZZjLJajs4cRun3PRLmglOVumrSuvthtr8kx/RqepbSYqUz1Wr6gbjL1pOq1ZzwVuxVK2Wgpf1RKJ886pnttQCaGu5XDJZrcLLVgA2A68h2BKADV7yANVw9Y4vBS/2D@i8cZAS@Rge9M/FQiJDXyvAD9/ExYp4717C/6Du1nby3j2tnLm8DH3GY/BSF7xara7ptFron728FFsirRko5@E9U7q8VDPllBpP2k7iKX4xCbJKSCr7SKtTrmUQvlqumGT/IBcAy29uFnL1eiEH7kIJZy9vXkQNJq7HYxdBz11MctEYX1fEKjdEoXW7eLGLqxhVO8vlkwkQrknQ/q5i@Me91XKZ@ydZrpAopcr@X20tyeqgivA/tLazqdxGceM@KGn4N116oUyuXhg19ap2YVRw1PKq2vG/V4n7fI1797JlIGspUz0RWq2H28fbrVZNFEXsVeGGniTdBfxM1tiJN6jK8@VmA0vYPInHK9X7xB5qKc@AD/x4Uhy6CVYqEyEEs4eb@KH0guqPZawJGj3xJpT9EQ7wjGG3zn9duFiXtVkfL9Znpmkykw3pYkPGw@ne6YSRbH75oeErpcUr9DHCS4g9e7y9s3uc1jYlFtP2tnfS2tHzBzEVX/PzdwrO4vvh7vbDg@eQ4Nnj3e2j3Y/3P919/gz8XXY@vwI579/nz6hryfs5eyF84bzRDUM3JobROp9Mzl@zL0yzZUL9DSdQCLvvMNdoAe5jfV6OKvw6pqt/8YXujOli73747Xc//O/e/fZ33/32t9/99vd/@uX3vw2/H8Pvu/z53X9XzuP9p1/@i99591u/DZ7/CX5/CL@f/PTLX/8G/9H7H8Hvv0T8/sj/ReLxnwCwfumnX37vRz/98pd/AL9/5f9@cPP3Kz9Z/vv@t1b/MN33fuf2ON/99/D7XQ4riPvd3@J@@LwR/7d4vF/@wbtf@w/8/0/8P3T@9rtf@yO8@S///Ad/8l/effM/alrpT/7tu2997923vvnuW995961/qr379X@rZqK333n3/d//yz/43b/8g/@R/n9M9999n/93P/jnf/6//Pn/9ud/4P9@Ar//AK6f/Pl/hLbxN7//Q/z/3u//zR/@EP//p3/9N7//q3/zS/@GHL/BHf/3v/p3/P5Xv/Kf//o3v/OXP/nGX//qT/76N37/L//3X/4/f/0//9V//3t/9c@@iZ6/8ZO//MNf@otvfvsvvvUv/@KbX664f/vW@5fv4f/lP4LP@@P5PnDep1wf6vPl3wmfvw815rkAnwB3/@K7X/8FYPBfY@zdt3@Mi@Lht@L/x5pKcX7M3/4/4NBulhlDMuCC36@@@/Z3kUT/A5AI/kN6fSd8WQjhL9@ZvwBZf3NJol/86Zf/8kf0FjMqdRoIx@66pJVSG2DSbJTLfpftj5FDkl9YhBYC8HP6DkqohbDvoGx798NvvPvRP333w99498Nfwg5TypXT22lJvWOCASLm3yMeRiy8TzyM@Bnmn6LRICn1Gbyxz/zAzz77TGhdKrj74v4l@H5GXvxiPAh3Z/hBQRj643YNdsmibt@Z8Z3rvm@YM2GBuaZI0dgItKB8lk1TPkJTHLbEJ/hDpOkGOad4J18Mngp4m//PnVOBpTAOv/ArUYGTHH46PwvuFPKQTWo6DchFahnjqtAG96EpN8o3V2ZYguk0NQV7FxyQQwqCHqRYrVZLYcIaxwdeOWr1EiNUUqkalBtT8zTpVglBTB8QFEhZSx2y1kZtyhOmEF49IEdKQK9DUdXEVKn2EDKsTR8yhIXACeyrV7V6qTatI7i3nB6paeoB4YTAaqlp/S281wgmpBNiD98CKqVaKlUvYYZYSF496RavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCJo9hb9xn7SFRLYotrh0gwHhvvqXlsjAjRIfwkteEXh/4DJ/02iOBrlJWfC@PhW6SIbnHdFCMAXEmSZZnBDyfttth9CJ5yUCnKFh4pDiFFHEEcEHowHPZJCSmq3xS9QP6x2sYHXwgMC7O@vi7E6mJWPJCJdIrCnNMKLSPHlVVoeFSYWCiL6G3QmvoAF0hfpfzX4zj3EGccMPsoxX/372@wj6CY9Jz7CUxKZe2cHeNQNlMpUQP4dTslvAQLRAA@JUCXgjytkZGTEtJpxuRaDMPYwcGBjwR5vKwJKWBzLaviO07HTSaTGKSQ5bScTvtPmZ7kIfsOmUL9p7yOxKUvjjJNy1XBUKoy9GJRq0YFAxg93759C7VCS1Uq@2CbMn/VipYrUSB48M3nw@Es2Huh5coCt8uZWsgxlqBhULiSLCmwBNtICnyBM0ciuBJxrVSKUzygvpzYCBYxFVRiBxwCjdUR0eDixmIpnwwCdw7YzsGTJ7tPj8fNJhMM@oKq0Ro7dsdw3QSGbT99yBe3a@VCMtZoIOjjioYCRtitZEj87T883D@qMF5ovwoShFiVpp78YpZVITYev9iM@Ys4RPw6kC0e4b0yL1tCK2chaawuxDoGWhQ4p4hmcJVVhSdu/4E9BZM/LYpptYBmXJIGfpnwdXvC8Ow6vtEd2hQueZc3N4kCQv1CooF5dEJtFYR63V/@xFShfrR7DAmOD5iqZWSh/hmbypihdCXUh7WhYfW9wTquIxJPMmKkTOuNTBr/tGwW7mqukFbzxeba2vBCwjxPqNoucEHYFbxeSFiMr8DFhK8I7CvgBRfkgau8mL/Ebv@g6q9zwlNiEnyxk6jmoZklhROoaA5OGEevKvyAwcGuj/yE2Nrnn3usXgdrWtrfE2IgMAYsWO0jmV15IFNNdyeOQaF9xrrmpyZ@@Unumu54qM@g9QBBYldXVz2AtL/HtLpGrzxFF@9XHfJpg/tqqgsxq1KpvVVzRSGnVSpvs5omgIewoeByojXgAZpt3VD4X9WFTLLZkgLCShVFeGSzWQFHhYUKfhEejxeuaeEl4Hpr6aPpR7WaxPx1IBlaA0IhEMD6nsMyQViRh/lvBYHe/v9rxUVTJpvjejajbipjcOrgzG0qOjjb4MxvKm1wmuAsbyomOCf1rJrZVCZ1gQmb/Jg3hrvIa6JnTPFUSe4n1l1j2JNxl0VNpAw0cdM/NrXup6vjdhVb79ZwqzFuLUgkL4R@7Zy2vQlGrS/jjnXH0odCt9a1O/QNWaErt@3uTHa92RA3JgxtpxYHdS0eBJj4pV/caFczQF/A4aitbDZXabCmPLbHW4KWL6YaagYEPf7UUlpLrxlbxWKlK3eGhu5s5Sv5UrqLex78CaOtfKbSlz978viR540PDdoIsZUrQwI87gUPZtgqVfL5ZqMhiqkGZdPET1tyMSKtrUHDM/SuBM@ebXmupJWakLhrOrVaPL6VVTVJrWQzJeEqpJAAtMUC1gVMmcKCpZG@F34rrVi2BTKhktbT5gURodLr9a42LlLzF0G/kPgbkOdK0tPti/C1KkXiVdgkLZnzQPDRe0D4C3@irCJq@ZJYbVTn78WCWG1eCfdHRtfUcfvDSebiZqoCyE4ONQYZnTDhquLYtldpGz3bMeYRs2ohiMgRuhkhJ16F2Z1kMMeLm9kVMBLQkFMOmJmfu1enJX8NtZxr7oI0aDQ3gxP5kIljL1/qer0OFXaRK2q5fC6vZQuFfFED6V7OFfIlaBuZQiavaQAgVy6Vi1csAV2Qrkv1WlbLCpomaVkpq0pqFv/vcGj4//7xNfjX8A6psppwjNvan0K3AV2dxR7j9ljPZsc2fiChzx4YnRUxdgY6LY7ccWzX/XvEeaBbpzzoocnPkguDHun4lRh3ZHqDFTGej0e4I95w/tEg7I7agCCJCYrwAG7O0LaXRSiy589WlPJJeHorEIMf3wrRD/c/fnQceR7vbu88EgrswcHTh9ceeT9Snj3e3TsOX4s8NEiaD0F8fffx4@uv/iN38PywN7Ed/Al7B89z81vohXvvhBxci5FCbwLi3/CVFCscRF9j@WLgUAVcsX0PjMN7vjNfmDsz6HzBNxaabriCmO8xrQjHwW5DnaEEaxusww8@QGuVDiXydVm1WBaEMbPsc1bMsK49HOr4ydveGngOdNw5ZaBCN6QvNmPW57Yz7J6bXWNNeIKbtMoqfl4UkRAeAZDRpEMngEAnj0fcdfFjtDhr0x5ODDbBD0Gv8IQHeqHTMfsD6MTO7SCC0NZ1RmuEPuyC9Eb08m738Hge5HcjZHgzuhATRPGR7unTWKlaz1Qq9@6pzxyxvJUV3b5R350Ct7Ln0Hp0Z5Yu5UVPFveY3Ir1zUbVbY6hxgrqaSVnj@s6KOINUFu9XqcKHeNWLl8B2tZLmfxf/eaP//aPf5WVylq/pp7EcQk6Q02OkbLmK3QyafdauZQvlbNaKV0ql3J5tZDPp1UtDYZRsQy6cUYtqYVSvqymS7lyFtiuDKH5ctFXB5VA/1M2KgDW6uBXLzfJQJAHYAnwyTr2JqEnWUwP3ydMNCCNKKAt5tFm1A2zBh0UUzMsW2QAUWcdFtvb28ns7YniA3zBRQo7GVHs4ku@lMkUH4iiQSE7JdRMRJunKeH5QaLHXzKZBzuiOOEA8OhdURzgy24BR5NE0cSXne29Pcynhy8apodopzyEvwyDlyJEs/AFFFgC8DqEBtG2eT45QnQXXzBLDNnjITsQJoofB@hgyCGPxgE8Ckq6vS2K@/xlextDdqjYeY7oJ/iyTZcoOvACLUAU@@DoO9D2RLENTmwHotgBV2emgx9@YRRPZ7U8XRRnnDxIIFGcUmy9cyqKrcAfs/nUxyaP1K3Qi8pLfZ9eyvgnilqANEbLhi9ZUcyFLzko26NHn@oDr2v0@TVz@LMDJX30KKub08nuXvvjj9v9ftuZbe9@fIhBOzuPQEeYTZx2v@0nbLfgsiHVziNNPx3Nrl9Q6v1Wq6IPlwZ90mrldOtaUGvWMhBDSPUaMPOvPmY0au1A0M6j1n192cQpAWyhCBjBs43XgxE8H@htHhRcFETPabstVpH9UeWm735DS6RPcKdHesexq/g@ra0xFk/E07NGIdOsUgAbgXKdqV7RB78TeNdx9CN5MWtMa5lmbVoranzRTS8hnky1vCmm10ZbajlfWdO3VC2XmlZwK7zdi7O4pG6xhHpv4w1LPE1uaaBdiydbW5LYUJtbmlqqFIovNyaimKzgfStbrEDETDzDGN6SjWJzq5iPJCkWU7qiVYrFZPUK6OFBn97GUYlWInFu6KfJJKKLNjIUgX9ufEblNKu9xDQ9rXG82CxZndbUKj@QkGVuwOri6beTjmc7HGIfwE23MhX6oLmolksi5K8oiWQSLVcyTRVhvsDvxdeOT4@PPwNJyIS6b7s/4x/rrfqvHz/akcGc99/w1Fp5D00b25F3UFwthPBDVQOvY1Du5UfQiYKdE/jhhiPHHsq7044xRvsoCAjOIpT9E@Tk40cLcI4G9jnPGfdrV@kYIqtjMDzU1@wyvVYHl95lCcKK6clz6r5b9XqtVRvRlmYoYpDqE0Yn3s7B7Lsc93AXOSW/wE04fkCrlrmqtmvT2BTgtGpMUl@N7O4rLdWpdvEs3we1B5i42oJnu2rUDPyavBgTq70tq8bYxHL1nvHMcPB8hP2DdVAmcGdOoseM5Do7oW/P76AJcCXVHWbNMXs6GSVALW8nF70ir0iaxNeCIl/QVjFcjHBV7dVY4mWy@hpenXWW6MoPklu5ajfxgLWS4JN51XvVYxor5Kr0kc0EQoJGRLTBMuvJWv0T0H844NNKBRDx6/gUYGJOANbsUoCeHJtX1U5tyBISm7IkkSdX7dcamPoSb5uSKDYlqXHZFOqS9EKoQzutzmJ6zZ206QB4lmmrWqZQnYKfWsxVB1Cx@stp1amNJ45RHcKrP5DFd8TpVSAnUA3AvLlMvPuFbyQ3pXyN@1UJ1OUQVI6W3KpNqxYeKQUsUcvWICDVyGXSYBXDrZiGbl4rpNVCOpvOpaUi@kIfn86nwROsG1ArEsOEyJiYzkwzsppWDTWdyLwyu6@S6dMEqC1EMpZMe/Yufp0efKCSkCvpFZ46S6a0jSGDWrCZvikRm4KkqGLBgOYDNjbTAwR1aOhDSpFMSiy7kRiuJzDO@vFkvNtoViq70/HXICghvd4qpIqZ1JtksppYS9Zc47VQrwp1lCpU6vEa8Kw/xsfcyagBdQwutahVGo02FrGYSWczWSid2brsb4p1sZnOrBVUqKIrRuoR4xIjOuaFSs7cb9xCrXtoQNWpZa0qyDQ2lS1pUlnJb@QzfBCMpxTGvlhDSrLEiRjs/kzE40UtHk/GqzgCvyb6Q64gy0iOxUGoxu@pWyLoX2JFLGsYYS4SaYNfJsAONLArAUcUWK4sxC6Eq4urTTCJFVqnCIojWyOXJNfvC7EKY6AGnvjnzShrjH3o8sfUZv0lf57gem2AK9DZj6CB0rIkw0QzjH2Ke5m3WBwQ051RQ9OyzYZWhI4MhGMQFYzxKk46xHBFuFwHCrsXgN9mqo5HcHzCZjM9Fe6EusdYP7UuUJlj1ycWt2vb/cPtYNHV9g6Oqp6Ani1W42LsIh6LX8GfELtPe480vveIxSK7j/jA@s/F78fi8TiOYAOh3sZIRrCdi2Boq4KfIkroFS4RGs3k26fm8KKUlfjgBIioq6vYukI1E@zl@OSVBkwRs@zAA@whHASCziqfx9HhmPJq7H6ulbJP9g@sh86ewfjWjlKuJdZjLKNKuFWiWvF982Jr7VQFnsiK2dN0jN2P0fJusVzSRI17VGPsVIqrFb4dZHxUfll8WXr55PnB84M9IXaydrlm40QACxepvbW@@jWIGM/m4oyd1GLTWq7qL1Gr1yV1U8MjnoqsAuK@pxakzGWds3WdAgoahLz7hR/kppsleNcyKrxrWj6l1evqhsaSsfG7L38PT@u42P10@zGL49jx3/7xj7Ti3/7xv6ZlX/ErGk/WssUYxESnWijGLi7GFxdXcPGwfKwZ40jliklw8@kNNVZXVC1rWVaVVRRd3yimctp9q6r4cdWimoy5UsyfqCnmY@6lH6RlShAUzKSQl1jAKontHpp5Tb2/idyihjvVWPi3abjlmBArPXl1yRi8dOrdft/UyKUorPJWYptvpU32Ficv3kpr7FWtjpPfKgSGI/sbuI8HJ7ji9ZSyEWdg/bB646raTDGaHQBj8aVhbFgn13j9ZI2Vy9e8Niz4MzZc@sNEgYcLr8GbsfGFKyY2korS7fonQW0aLF8HVthQALONYHCf/0nSSfLdL/y6phX@9o9/5bJ12fpMA2uxXC6oWuxnP9ucWBPX6NZ/BglvOXshsPhocgQPSUBHaCmyFd@ylztgpE4sVI15/MBuREsRFQuzb4HJj2/CGSpDVHstfvxXN0HRNnBrdppUazpuJ1kVhFAFJdXZ6XfSBINt4KdGoDkLF8JXMAh6XFYDSSt8ZQ4KPEbQx9qdljucOGPaaZGgdGozze5BEsjhK3iy2hptKffFtQQiTtm4mZSj7BLVSHFiI8N18Zw26GmEr0AS/1hI/IK6jqcfYEzTgv5BxiiEJwV0G5B3E/Ie8gQt8k1Q6XmENOPY8UQWqNfCV0BjICqYoEgwcxMiVEEWfQUIAGVI@IDNJttk2SS7MFOp6vwQuCtcZo7H7enBzmsBkyG0Lu70DxJXMR54gVqPHyJDvvBrGHS4iGcAhMPgU9U1MAwwOb2hZkZHI7w3KIBFxxAlqGjs3r05VrWa2U0yKhHCPzXHOLBF9WAtxxWABUbVR92KmGZ4vF418A3ZDiieInSB6yR@rl41kpSJ@HolCPD/3kyLHHmtqiigigXw64u3ig6QDBIj2XkddthmjalaMclC5DuAe4eQoiPdQkvxZPqRrH0WBF4Bhj@LBcf8g4A6jg4W@nx7fes9g55ygmes4wFMXBj4W@b5EUso6Pa9IHWYCopiDil2z3TAiqE59OB0t0RWTWKy@Wl4hActHtdyuOxayyfxQakwNoOnjqeU@fms0ekqHRsq1B3bFh1rRseu4Pp44AiQUf6JUBztiXWO3@Tw64YSRzFy6TQo5HzEmI5po4@ZUlqcxG47YOoGtEkzoy@zzqjLtDJLEKPRyVVWCC5JiQjhNqjESOP20BgBSkeGQZuf3Iqi9EGjmrTp@K4nJvDVYM@E3sZyFf@7scq5eWoqx3imuGT3cI8UPwwhhkoYNj8@X@4flTW07VM2NE8NPgacWDhKwmVgFIBemwbKzn9A2AouxNCyaZaB4DSPBb8iPIrcWUpH0q4lZsmbz6y6lmhhjV5S52M6@E3YM92K0JeuS8G3g92ZGxxGQ0eqwLscilzDP4aiFscN5uH5KoJ/rE6NTnSRcW5hnACrNDiOBp3C2DHOGFq0AvYxIDQ7wcEO2IqhtF@hDoDaHrQsPKXOcyp4HAlg4nQTHWh6voC32EcsqwkYkZ8V5J/rAzCw6muL0CEMkmI5XK8LFSPTgDrKFWidoy6E4UZ4n/0wfcDd6KYTBOfszdZ8cNjpUF41xptF8JKPvGDrQH6moq9BYAEwXILJWkJMAdiUmBQ56DD99eSc2wWSJRV2E1KaIQSf1ACFVIXgo9Es8vEMAQIe6C4/Ydk/w@78/FymgxUnjikbLn5QwsUvYSvjvglqtK14xmjsf7rPxE@2@nDnLol/Rwa/j741pS@Tl@/N@FMQem7NX86SiPfcOHaOZ/i9hP6IDmHC049cYqg9k7610kn4q2s4/2nN9EXAfxXkP6kUv0IgjCGYaXqW7qQBWLrdOU33zrtVP@CMGiQAh1o0Ak887tQJXkZu4DLHvTCG7aEcDYPaw1OaaAVIIh@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@qH9gaIlVkJWmNVqUMRZjTdL3i4CknKCh8lcP9ksYAQ/PRcgACOzNJnhJ5tGk01rNS442HRFsvMIklNCcsqT8NjTFUg2/WRgPe0H3QtWTxO0U1xcKAI8lXejoAaNRYYfRsbp7i/wmDmcIPXznMsc4gKfh1DFRj7rNJfm3oggHRFa1wAgI94A0OVfIqwI1wWeKoVvoYzipAxkFH/z2YDLCmAwEsFVfhRrImQysoFB4RdT1A9A2xVTDUFUafAX/zL8J6YDz@Cn3vTMLMZUFz0z6Wt//yieTaRspIFGtA81k0OBjJbMc8s/wzCqc8Two70DG7S69rnNEkuUbfBXJn5SpT2028pIx2Ur@H0y/5vd41kysB9w4oTdH9ue7tm5XIUbTSax3bL8uc1g9i0bP2sQOY4ZdL2ubbhW3INK7dh9y3SNNMOT8k4N3@ww/HPuhaie7DttVxD8YUtuxiJozleo6rZa@MXUViuBC/uSlXCRMa3zQ/aMxwW0f8EVSQ/iyQd6ME7Y7S@Mjpe8GyaeLe4nOzY7p4mDsR@IQ6zbDGRYB/R/CB2ABsNce2450rnFqEq3vQSd7T@wR3YftL6JKwuY@hr4/TlsREgfjwmXNNPRpK1ETpinVpLopPWkn/STD07KPtESejJMry0CWCBGmjnXaYyUdZZk11qZHU8W5Hf04fgeRfE9uh1fssKv48xN8xoP/LCss4k5BIg4RyN7NxpYdJBb3RvoLKASeqNexRO8N4pdWhbWRUy3Ieq2H13uAX@kwzcX3kLEP11F/9srMEi@@77Vp@NnpI9mIG9GuNwxQV@icYMZ0ARE308mhdiS7ELWfvieeUFc/AjYHqoQoMaS4LLwyFVomGMwu93wswEB4Dt4Hldi3eB7Wp5V44FLcHLO0uxUW11FD1tdY6jPjG7Cj5mOwA1KfAgGG8mr9ys4CjoSeja39RLQdyXDUOjGkeg8UmUFy@jps2RyNVvxKGbIPTRSThjur6Yfht8QzTjEV@Oj1WAHxOMxHI49M3H4czwbz/ip3kP@PRJfjvL@h9ckHoJwN0GADrz3VNPzbJO3ic/DRFik9@gRwrjyYpHx0N0AIh7xc7MOP4xEd5cUKjeSqBbUsrD4PYvlNW7eVuMRrgh4kk8tvR9L3sV0781zEVbjwOYibOfDupAbkHHRRqeTiELkPrfWmG3dkAnoR@N01opepbVEoIYpSdJ5JpnbpF8kBbSM9@GJA06fwhMB9g2vxRkqKBuOaflf9mIUMtLHEa3F9wElHaBEqMhJ7qMRiSUEboh@cRXm2VmZZ@dGnp2FPMMWsJhlJJLQWcjSrwWsntuqYGj0vBXSGYPQdobHbWIbLsvWHRytuIib8YqZZvGzeAUEctyIV3YTIJTj3XjlITnceOWIHKfxyifgmLet@GW8EjQLjODAKznuo78vwvG9E6/sJJJXgqefGm6QrxyvhHUKcbb4K1EESIHlBq0Rp9gs2y@m5xjQsZFSmWbIMW4azScah0nTLwP//As19O0KDMQxzg2KzFJMXeg0Ij0Gzwe6jeBs9CUtueL35rsHe7ToKYyC2aTAxoumIfCghsfii8KII4ahNKMBT0AQ5WZlOUYs0pO9Jzp@7sChVMmL@RP1ZNIHugkKb0Dk5jwT@iyRnz6or0UQvALfD09MvArPG@gE2RFGOCebXIIWEvVV/JZCYV0v4uLXfrSGaKx7MRJ@hz2IwmuJwEZkOuhwNDmHmY3t8SKTUCgurjejaWhQjjdK5N5ryUgq@C1zRTB5@yVDwRBt/MnbihNJh6gtiCAMbGSavJWF/QLJYgyay7qIpsobH6AQkTnQwo3OKX3y6aHvpHhc3KSpr1jVDQVpeZYkuRbFJCSW8VSpie7x3EPjdRfPmvow8zVIOcWxlgQCiKQMc@Hy1f4A/d3m@nugUAdEuJbBMsV6eVd6U72@tZe9hvlwnu3NCsTANHuYXKochTnMSQ7WQUQzv43Xbqj4uOSDK/k80xD6NW0/IFtoE9xBt@u2BYeFWoJztuh5qoHnqbaaUDc1kuGZHCgtMubkw@EFDzGdF@12XHnBl1UxhtD4tj784Ap2Fis4WnkIjwrgXCM5b@XOxKJVLvO2DWKb@6BIVSuMC3KaLg2ree4J4p6mbsNpW/A4aB0@PHj6@OvQ6RaLxaTfR8/m@GGrxbHWsB/nkGkFddgfLDFbtDR@lwUnu3E43h3Yjrd2Yok3ZAkX1qAM6JBLwH5@G0/6siwiz6@1XUjH40Yo6sM6nTcDfUEqoaqjY5dt@nT1gCCGl9jQfSCBegv0TpO1lqQvkLRa@J37Vou6r1YLFy@1Wn4vhlUTzIgnfxZbUyauQ18G5Z/PORcEOj6BPTxgLx5tH7PjR7ts7/nOJ@zrB8/Zi@2nx7hz/tnzB4/3dxj8dp8e7TJhYWklfmoMDUqg60OjY@D3I5mWyeQYQd6xxzMudxI7Se5/pI/YI7tj4DTVpquP7g/4i2wZXp2n2gVzdIZjmCZ9Wm5kerjegr6FBmYsKjdd2hCIC/4ZxG2DTTtCm3dkd82eCXEFtH3HpuEGe8jY0IQaBHkbbC9OcyUJP3tGS4foc4a4AusckusQH@duAIzO118hiTEG/05aV2Y@4cLrgyl4vHv45IjhIQw7B08f7h/vHzw9YnsHh/D67Ov7Tz8Geu4fHR/uP3iOQRTxycHD/b39nW3y4AhkZIanI3wxcb1bUZAxOlGlc4oz3/IYqj98@3@Ku9alNpYk/Zt@irKEjRpaN2wwthC2AGFrFhsPF/s4AMtCakGfIySOWoBkmxOz@2NfYPf/PsK@yrzD/NqnmM0vs6q7WhIYjydiHGHU3VWVlZWVlXXLS/LUGyt4dd1g08hQzV12IX2CRif44rfmSs5liOULzDH5qkBlZiu7r97TnK/833HDaa6CWf8gdRByKL7Zglrl2miwrNF4KznG3WEmW3T5PuJ8pBCNwy@x14QMP3vKAGclnlbgq9QGdFRw9i3OFXgsG9BU0QOCDVBGYaWsOIrO3Jy3yiDXqLZmpwc/mFKbKBHqFxR9aVRNSg5TTOvKACiMGmpdnAcVS9EH4nv6sKirHfQlg3ocfZAM6ol8wFK0Bt0RtaRzXA52LiGe1bJ8@PX8YouvhdXT6MN6g3exKxon6Tfu0oaKopDB1USHYyXJKQ/Hc2yEzSDgIiHnRxyhTkcGhi8R7EgmylUi67ZRzhQJmzauGrTamwSGRSpxA/SEGu1BqDJlN6f2oRzkdwOJUnXaaXRFBSpW3WHeUyvw6lNe08uHKLoTm4lc9JgBEVkuiUdUblOvCv37lqOS6xM1NrSOJEdYNCpo30NgfQKBfwQMAUpE7Gg0eaZia1WA6bU1K2fCHnEkzm3/sPMTO7cum36igNbayvwafPniaiJ7iX2S0VNk7KiLvvh9WlbyVWa716cxzmKV4@FACjbPeheDQPowk2wB3zjxNEe5MbFRbZ8NcXVtoMN4jd1e16r0hLj4llpPiCnvUytzvNydR@IrDpRKnE@TsOjdAZ3GSe/Kt@7OPFwiXfs4fqGFMN@V4/BzNGBMZP3pxLLjD4X4iivltc31o@wfnz0EWRSxIDFOjdIh/hNjoi4aHnzPxwqLfay79EgzwbHCyxOU1jp4WlpilBtgtA88C2hf97JeitJE3XjyOwxpxr/zx2/fylIqC8mkA@OGZ5lYunnq0FTpcZljpVVALNlJyJKsz5gvHsOM5PVLGM@gF0pEkS7kCPbtY6GntAgxrTu5bJNk0RFAdXdH8F21xhoVcfhkGMXY/ZH/lFkvL6y5@VihRFnkzBgR7RnIRde11FJ4vpoAt3k3OJLf9we3cid2Mj38ELTNO6H9EG7ZhdthybRkwbo/2D/uACuT2z8Eltru3Q5YJslJaBGnR8zpzaYjbdq7a/w80Xc89ggM5l6coERArdouu3xFbdxOZ6SAa4OJF0R7@5vV3V2Vkv0JlSW5hy1DS4tBwH6g3sXatkGXhV0uWjTZvqJl8WS@JDTazL@7BvNU4t0iKvQaxNP0iIRFHCi8HQxF6umZhZcQrH3PAtFQLondVyODwkMN@Ib2gIRs3GlWA52pzUzL5BOEthK4ppsna2Nbh581rGXuRlzN/sgGZOsENU5hWTK9/z7I@vi5qUcWWPAZhAa3aCVN8w3tE/ao4gvKmMsle/CObjFdCiV7WWCnDe2g@FVIrrB/nqGYkWQRLmthS6zrxbFGTdbHs2aZwwqJmAYa0PTUiaLRTAlGxPOXVbtD3XjSyySnIFpkItLiS5srqPjxjZ7CmBrRPFmOFuT2WJtlbA4Nlsc4ndWwS7dneghd6OVx8TBeFUnbO6vK/nOqklkiUZOh@dTGmESCvLy09Ph7sMdbYYpnfxa2zCHj8nNwfkH7@xhkOAr5eJ84t/bWM@kxA9xBOlGtNwNmrCAtdabMKYm282Rk40e4yLkQIQMn7AheOV6rq4ZjuE2HLjOSDZ2zTLTBGsJRQ2XUTFD/5u7qIJC/W9@DH69PBhsyQXXwBlr5b3r90I@t8iwHLtYnmLwmv/n9fpeziT3TOaBk2IzpTmM7trYThVdpFRL5vs1uSVtbJ4narWfOGrgSPl7MIV4tTvdK48d72WLJbupWbbuq5tk5YztxFpnqp1xL9jwIunchwDKYzyUwfbAN38PwOf0nHDwDksjE1nwZpo37XdyYIrRqPuQgPFotVMvW4njvt8Nmowu/H17qYahS3iMqyKew1Z0td9rJeqGUKE/IhRfdDJXyUtlciovSNxzoAlIShPQmvlsTFiw1jKYkzGtOe9CPwsWWP5TTM9acbOSLK4XlZw63rusNvPPDZ8fefLOcUjT5Nrrn4WX/uvXbae/sqq066uLXk2Fz9OV3pZaeqMdU1@Ij8ZBbXC7n2SnpU/q7op4VmHM1gi/Y2y/ip@YksKRScyreh5ceKAnvwZvm57CQGONSNX9uuBAmdoPy@eHycblbLpTOD7vHJRj5DRbKg4XiQgYfHtEsSjJGbuYPB8eYU@1TV797pRDwlgMTatMQxaYh9OVNox/0titvXyVO47AAwBGY1vXmA3WJVTsDbTbYnuS6/nVGH5N5ChzrYIHkzLBVUBH28HyejOOYVkCYUa94tJoNh/x35DozhdzlxaDHKcabIVhLfQu@OTPGjKnAJwqU5TAwPg9hX0Bw4jwZXAzJ15FoUWeLslwrwnbStUAcoiSLw9RRKgWbQiCqbbkOj50w5zeaZ0ACwZm/cTG1usqhmonVwhyf4kGVo9Fng4nCMR5xAUI/F3zbgCp45R6y2YdDzcd7EQ/yhc@oBmwnwwryDq8UkQL1b/WV7Zu4/CoRQAg/I2uunD7i1CsvWkiK7SAfLsClWXLjj2sGmFVKp8ygsYAt9ZVj4KwpzjRCtZpM9H3mGuQUWtE/3YJskd8mmhHldyU7k4TvqfVbCFpyl3LSGn46cbGMVSxripnMFilmvksNnHTR9uiNT8NqpDb8ToeQFlrMxOTAI9v36voXovrDQ9R5HCEv6dmJ9GwiPSfpglScK0cTfJzpuZ0plf4a57tRqTibN1FXWfHiJUc93czRkiTOW7orb5gb9OpBnHkt6krhyihhNZGQtVI@Tel9SXmQKBMxeJR@KOmavxd1z0dYJvK@TNaPX0d3kM/Ks1rXZIxLc92g88LRcX11CtgsRdRUSopzIEBlBlVZ22BqcUIrOJzz87BdK8dQFopG4vCYSa2tvkzl9CLjRWYcDbFinBhYU8aIRSWuc4EJN2SDRaqHkx9YIBgmGE2ZkbtmCo904ZEFFrkemGrFCnJigFPTxod4GXaR3/DHDPYkciZfenrijGA@lMaLdXOSQCx0H6SmkykpTWAuIh91o@6YReK6R@MQpwuJt9YpcFSnLzbYbRyDP4jkhC0ojKSYoHuUoikdZyga9r2tC5F44/w9P@@8atAa@6LjD1UF24wGW2E5CQP3gR8OQjiAYj824eXFRQe3jrzgu2YTau1LZHEJ1y0xRGtmzzk1aPZIfg9P2iCdCuXUDiBfQ0EkTggvT09hTAYL2N41RCtOXIJBzql0R3KgQWPm8aKYmfsKzjdYAHeCUxsJ6TkZPaB0eNFo@jmH1mghrX4caWo70AE0@TwddiNwMUZT2nPH@fNl0Pxt4xXuc58WC4@LFsmu9HVwIff4SWxgRUQyCYtwD7hUfOI41t1wU@6GswDoqW1M9O@JN/0rv9v1nQrNGJwxpEVr6Pev/FbOcXb96BIYcMHKuJmEHXbvst@Uwx1adDWIGWElHHpyHUYchl/Mz3Jd3OS7Ms/BpVV820xdfRW0QEBjcdLu4XaYLyzgJkDogULn/oCIMu@qJEp896xx4bXLOQ6iiBrwc2LdTURk6PYGQZN6hk@ynA6BkmuQuLJuawwTqq/ZacA4ODcNAZjHxBQwCJirpLtwcPSl@Q/hoHTDzB17w/RMnqRfj8cKDXe/H5D0jQnMvcLFLNypg/df1/bU3s7W/ofKblXR87vdnfe1zeqmWv/Id9y4KGd/u@r1zjZJl@g2XW7Nd@hDqrJHJVOc4FTeflTVX97tVvf21M6uqr15t10jaAR@t/J2v1bd81Tt7cb2wSbfvhME9XZnX23X3tT2Kdv@jse1mmJOXE7tbKk31d2N1/RaWa9t1/Y/co1btf23qAy3@hX1rrK7X9s42K7sqncHu@929qoKDXM2a3sb25Xam@pmjuqnOlX1ffXtvtp7XdneHmvozoe31V3FSgJWK9erhGVlnbawqInbuVnbrW7so0Hx0wYRjxDc9tTeu@pGDQ/VX6rUnMruR08D3av@@YAyUaLarLypvKLGOZnvUIX6ZeNgtwoXSaDE3sH63n5t/2C/ql7t7Gwyrfequ@9rG9W9knK2d/aYYAd7VU8hRiBXTTCIWpROz@sHezWmW@3tPs0ZB@@g7@BSJ38gwhCWFSq6yQSGGgRaS0Ta2f0IqKADd4CnPryu0vdd0JSpVQEVoFGxsW9nowqJiPt2M9Xb6qvt2qvq240qkncA5kNtr@pSh9X2kKEGhYyPxDpU6QG3Gv1EeMkjMatjONfj7lS1LVXZfF8D5jo3ccBeTXMLk23jtaZ5Do54rUOUoIczg8a5fbDSnvx05cMD5eSJzPQzmshj0sbOZpVmZO3PKhUnHNCsszLmSslOo5kmSqTXhMualn9yeVoPuu0ebEyjYnLwcR6eegiH4yKWyJFzRzQofb7CBdLpev19pU4b3b163fXuUzKBxvdK6GPwu3K5uo0IZoCdNw5@nj8Xuq8mCLX2SF90sqIeLiCQU6j/SFTfGue@q/L5lq@LwXgfgM3RUSjXJme4SiHRyMaOCIISV8knE/weaHbgghkDPtes45wUmpGcqRfSn@63@EUmB@sDSWc57srnsYllNIIvvqlGKmGXCPxHeyQI2lxlLvT9304zBbs67Plzp71eK@O6pgznHdA@8DTjfqf4iX86Vjw7Xp6R5WtnHSAgNPtuXsJE98@aZEr3S67PLcvgT33AP67BRnw@4NSUq@LDan1omXkkxaGR5Cnt2gLmFdzJWPO9qfxS@4DdXGHxSWns@@vou4wt6AvCUy1NeIdc7ph/Xh9LBhpg7IuDSBJoDxn5vFXG6JtEma8p4xkyXQctaP7QXH3m87xOJKGF7GWjY9eJ2bgfDG3sSQ6/2q28WT/Y2iLRCWyfrCw9XS45kdutXzz5/Yh62J0sex27oHmc1mmcZI2SDVr48Eix3HjH7M8MnM8jI/y0m07jj/DzEOltJDWZIMjQ3BARgbpQ0Uv5oENKsQOOB47h16kjUzNAJtFUF605bwx5id@gtRLzgFZm6Yy414b4A9jR8DdDPGqQZiDNYuxglziXdhcs91JbRlWUNzfsuAdZcinDx@LGLaIBH3Wx/iysa/lN87bVi6GoMmK8crdzSULiwTgWyuhVdGVkv2M/I/oAmL2H0ZdfNL/R40ft4I7d3TXCQWWwR2TcikrinDo@jNaNPtSQjxEzA07VTE2rCqf8rkaKx54@To4cg1ijgVFBcBXo@CYBlyI/IuNVsgbsyzlXfRVOhfMOwClpjtXvxLnTmqOhlIz/EP1uvFIogRU5ORGqXUd1OCbLx8iPhSFngkw/RQ@G/y@kyRT4q7TjJOgxtSwngPeiJEMVWtH2lYkSXJuLBut2I6am/eljDObG7pizqGH69mYo9jVEAt07I/PhI7s9bGemEABMjoMNe/xGKmlnDdo6vUy5ujjuSbrN84uM0nOFmSom4GaXjz1ednnmbgUvrnLlrMmqcJuKqpeycTvhUU9bprGtvHoYpgSca/x/5Of5ACQa8MylZ6K1Os5ZBT3KjBzQrpasCacVeUyiZenNrbd288pykZmQ/frmyxCKQK8Bn8l2cgCRnhL13KTHRZ6J1T57wYPTcGyTMflol3UnrIjZ8QHnYYsPQxBjZHCNCaIj0NlVXwxNZR6yoggqibUOYz@DELdujkjL0@p1hD2fTIJDI@wPuuKt3pdTLZMjJw4@NIa2uXxOvWmMCOXO/ZotLJaf3@t50F1EZXIsocsjnkqz1@vT0rGBdhOOXjByc@qDPnTwu@FlX/svpPks6OsTCbPop2qwbJLdO08z4iieUQuDAawVWjnmD27SuQ8NUXFPMswuqwwxr@HRNXPoGAwXiiqzGqesEk3YLSkTcVUtq2/fJJcQVLsM9ZmCQRhtLlhnk@vBvUM0/K57/d8w92MJ1G35rcgzqQWSzwKlk2pd9vHYHEjTL3ohn2hQV@AEJKJEUQ7SIkVVmqOfanbSek2p2DsmfJdyS368nohJjbYUVRQzrq6dmG85S50JKi1q16CRs9Di4hKjMm3DdXPrZoy9hSavrVXqqBuJlOeyiCg/NEtHPIncjJ4@4kkf8pcfhhg99AV33HoJCoSxZsW96qScY/ygU/Ah8Pst@0yUVjKtxgWO33jr0@syL5qjQ@32r9kYhP6IdgDNfDDMM4x65k@9s259o9dpnAa9oEH7NPh6H4rEw@OIH9Fhp/3edcihgjihZWVqjeJn8S8jbtjwHt1LlizXXOHAv8jYagqD/qhyJm4i@OQcSoBxmE7m74txH2lRmSdLcSEnaX/K@nhFt3Rr2cfFaYXlRh8AtIBbG9OgEBvSARsmWcanpYkMJ3dlsHA8UVnVcG/R2Etg/IxIxNcwCYwNMhNqCXYjsDO7FePD1tBrsQ/CPhwt@Zs@4t2EGf7sNRD5mKTIC2gKPFfFlYJVVG5RhvBDiIfR7eRefPovxp4Q@An0i4@nccs0RmAR1zbelkLZr2gvo4QLqwcGLKNZEpMUC06DrmV@yJEmhuNQk8mj26jBmj@0KNJu9ia4EiMyQxsfRLTL1Enk1EcuJpU5Neey3w4sQSqDTOF2hvW/pz/Lgx@XuHJyBsG0oSFnLKRvI1WTqITYsmPqtTbK4lP5@yNmcfG@vTZGwPI0lTMrxnEmZVYubIESyPyKa61en4Rxaox6WtVjLhz0LubuSb1bZcdUz2zTaN103e8qAguzlWmynG8xacsjPI5Kzjg@Y0yTpBhrmhEPYfvKzxGbjxNxWK5jvJXro@/Q4TaaxXpT0aQS9XdLxj4mxSto9JqJJhpSjDuclJai74d1anj9dgmiYcr2qs4Sow6RUR/JowVqjEwRle5PIeY@jfsYPVpEOdTbItrZ/XMrUceV5IzLU5OUcHIJesJxO4w2SS5dtKF8ATdxssKNhFS04Bx6I77KK2ZP4GQYCQIQq2I/G59DyQlu3FljfMTRAdqZOrSFipBE9LRmazhETv8jgrFXfn24ozUe6qNs8bgkkIYRJNpVcK67IBl7c3o9rA8ZygQpaIhPIUXUognZdHb/Vv1sWygfQZDSnKw1fQseGuOqBcKG/thJ9SHWwHFVumRiRCUHQp1FA40F2qWcdnzZrmL1F/SF46HdoIcRbSDkcwY/C7oE3HkvFyJqo8iwNUIWV5NbRpursmtSJGYoeQf59VCUpS5vXAmALxhT@XKRIMCtKWOPSwF2vWNzXgJR3UdUsFzEsKSP7BU11vOckg6i6gxPlqwchWk5ntkwslOB0MJiep4YEVqzTM8SQ6GJbiouVo6n09sT56AFseF9oTh1he6VJA2jnhMCcrDmghtLlMOi8gqagznxyZKbSIz4m1OfFazUwngq0SfC8DBbHE9dKSRSE9UuLiaLJkoSPVy71kQikcK1EY6kws/9Y9MU2@V5pBNqbTISqwytn41g2rTLpH1b7tdQrbJRtlljGHi2ZbjZftUlxErCKfvdDtjVHF8ZwHf7T7fWaKYaTHSsAPZLZ4xdMrIh5BVrClM9moWdrvG0FzkoMHvaXlu939/aSrh9PRkZRaNzv79UKBTAxCe283ujW42jpKCXT@bOty87nfzF9Z/670/yLPt9n0MCPDc7aJ@6hAZFmOv1TyUyBHCgrMid1Yas2Otfttt2CAbcUKLzqNskp/aGoHgCCiKll/f7fADEIPUE@xkNRPs@q2j0XTdkoamhmGsoKg2V4KuUuT0j8uBDG/rZ0U0VA4NgNtpMNG@55bWvmEEQ2YQ7i90Xu19j9eTUa7/T6XnqA4INw1PAzM14ga0tu0BBsuCGka17L0P2R@sp/yroWHbFyGLzOsCZicnEmTB@4eEbf9c/rQ4vMqnDTymaVqjJC2jmAvxTeyp1mnK1s/h7gBU@JLTvlfu8cZFpMp3GM9NUr0dw/EQYPS56U/c@iSwun4lpmn0/N4g6Hd0cO2ugpru8FjC@7Ll7uSW3ZI@ImzoaFtugYUFgaJzgc@V@JWBq9q8Ti1eDdvt@UpHDAEjH/pBElEgoPycQ@Q6AR6AefkRPeNH@tywN660xhyKywEGwjkm5gwJ1FHCch83y79eZSqWiZi8WFlSlsk4P2ayqrFfUJj6sr6tNel/H@6Py4tJSSWTupvuVPq6bjzdqnWDwCedC86y/Sa@UVobdGLS10cWz@fKsV5qtl1fXSmH@sLIOs356@tu//@ff/uO/8hX98j94WeeXw09Rplwul59tfp19dFPC@@Hm8dzsyeHsxfHcaQlc9nf2Gt6rDbKNWH001z9x0jILWF9Zj9Tss9n7jC6qTCDA80b/N5Iuz1W6GebT@msokaNYxqabvvXdhx3lCW3hTdCB8a08IZEmoCMcx1PvNH0o4NF8Q5QkXKAHKuXlbsUc3MMdTJQhulVJa088vGa98mHTEntSgC0uzVjZoBv6XZyAX/GaV5rnOA36DQZ1zb/5T2/C0/XeUM0fZdR8Qc17aj6V4p/i8jP66s7mA1jnSjbaDqRSHqXEVwtQM1RhwAs93j9wrJ0xcjvOLIfsASTjpoIzixWcF@3@2FhGAq6Fp84M4m0qOSLhSyYUSX@d7d5Qt3ylHDephKkNLxTqehfDlVk3KlH/YgnUCEURIK75XAjyvEdV4qaPLZLxlDdfdF87HE2IAYOsu6@2eNzjA81Fs12t85zYSyHMEavPy1fMjSUxhma0kSL1xwjwhYpsJwtsSTiXnnNEy9tqJTdTrLDt9mnmE12HkT8wuulS6A9lMYFoc9uEm@1quxatyC3XKyoVRNcrVlWpcd1v5VhFzi87g@BCmytw7RhQX6PabmQkoUcZkMARn/3PJ0cYHxQYT1Fj3SLBskaq1UPTZSR0tWk6dbCbk5sjiwj5Txka29/GxrabZysRww7CA4xUpMrXbgSdUHtd6TOxTxv9E0QHbLQ5oNpA7s34PA8hVscw7rUjpHMMmVXO4/FMTUlf9Bun5w1Ppd/29vuNUY2mLVr5DJo5l1oIF0xAAoNPVz2teQZhaZHuEqZI1BTWHELwgs5Ih0eTvk1FNifoUjMUtNsVDIIEOzEl/W@JvhqjY8zVP9AJNsoTwju6jdQiliUvNI00pJRtNsPDbGLoOKYGe@xEAyflCKrRyDS8oAtdYqI954tfkuQd@AjQdae0FaA2RVh@hvoxO5363UZicrroOMbQP19SMi9iPHMoStFGckxw1GIc8Q5Y0TryU9ILhMxNxp2RM5PJzByFOpxb2p5H2Ml3pIufb6ggCkDHAczYMkQddAMRlmMzVBwDI6dqrPlPENqdxinhN7pujMCKR@nMiwd59/DTUfd4PnPU/Xb0xWVMtEg2s2xWpfVltpFYeqzQzJj3Eq9GKy00rgaPuskMR10lNiwWCQiRfObwU/74W54QOkoj8PxRWgiS6DJgkr@7vjzA5yfQTCexyKedGXfeNZ2feVF0Fc2t/Is@lA@u/BIWZlPJx/S0z@m3CRTb6f5@KSYnYX5lsfBksfiEdkKn/jDb9y8x32bDyxN/SEuJENtZmnqOviS4IUGIm2HYKNHHIbVTwpqI7UmojZS0CNXDnOtxIraiMjnhCcpPVGZ3qTBxcaM8DVw@YsPvKWI5k5d9QYnqoMV9GcyfYe8c9TRCyLVx6xDhSGgZiI4IH6FmAdkEX7mNQ10zXObYzimnNuC7lYFQ9@bT1mzR7XWzerHm5uZKWETDaqazUlgpjI/RiSGaGKGzejE190AV1148/et/7/yeHqTXFvMf@vQ7SP@eXl5JyyM90Ntj83aVXkuvItvyTXqUpz0wPT796/9S@bU/ERykjFbpz9qSgbU8Sq9ly1zkW3ptmR6Ki4tU7//95S/UhlnZsSEW62zdU4xYyVBko9Fl3qV0VUMrZVs6F4sVNswCDNEwpL05vUAxari4UuBjurTWqrjytecro4@ip3hWzBqwqpCcZBh9CloZSYEyKsgKSKNC0VaW7oZR2wDzxmiqzw9zyyHtAD5rdY6oykh142EIlaFZ2RZRB2akRtrPy8Na4UUqUu94njI6JSWzhMTWTsvalcel/wc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/02y63)

Rexx has nesting `/**/` block comments, `--` line comments, `""` strings with `""` escape (not `\"`).
Rexx is the only language in the polyglot with nesting `/**/` comments.
A program is still syntax-checked after `exit`, I don't use it.

Rexx parses `# 6 "($11k ... tqx\"` fine, then block comment is opened.
`/*` breaks Pip, which is fixed with line comment (two spaces). So basically we returned to pre-Pascal solution for Pip:
first 3 lines use line comment, then ``` `` ``` string is started on the 4th line. The only difference is that `['][']`
is not commented out, which is fixed with `` `'[]'[]` ``. This should break Japt because it cancels the effect of `['][']`,
but it still works somehow.

Rexx/bc main code:

```
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
```

Nothing changed for bc, `#if`/`#endif` are just comments.
When we reach Rexx code most languages with C-like preprocessor are in a state which accepts any garbage after comment is closed,
just `*/*/*/*/*/;say 338/*` would be fine for them. The only outlier is as assembler, so
`#if`/`#endif` is needed. `#1""/*` is also for as, `#endif/*` doesn't open block comment in as.
Now `#1""` is hidden from C89, I readded it on line 560.

Golf of the last `#endif` (line 595): `#endif//*` → `#endif/*`.

Last line:

```
... */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/-- ...
```

Additional `*` is for Paintfuck.

Answer (score 3):

## 342. [<>^v 1](https://github.com/Astroide/---v/blob/master/udlr.py), 15475 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a 5    z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S    &rem     / \            mxf             a5 >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                     ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11p&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__





















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hatax@#8;c;>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogr61k5:4op>a>std[]!![ ]?42ore>805在ｕ 892g=1*\'\0C0ullrlot
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSSbfUt6pULalu3b4UiwWSIIkrEmABoESWpIrunt1et@2Z9fS0He22x7fdM55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKq8iNiY2MhEUjk4@TJk5knz8nHQVt3Bz/7WQwv9swezvpD22Oe4Xqs65hnhiOzBzN2XzfdvJYVBIy17fQnI8Py3IoQYypjQ93qT/S@wXrm0DOcNHMNg7WNoX0O4RpjmxNr4hrdOrxlGbOMc7ZvdcwuQGCefWpY5hvDgbAcYw@N4eXo0mMdezTSra7Lxo5peRSaZ@yZDi@9SeeU6W3Xc/SOZ9oWBBUYe24N9VG7qzOKPnYMnqjIAFTnlNIshpQYe2I7rgE52B3DdW30LIOn7pj24@2nH1@Lr2bYxzogNR4a02vZqyp7YRpO93oKjX16vLd33TfLPpFsi@3dREnNse2JZ@971@Hn2XbfsHSmyWVZux5YAGJ6xrCUKWUWgiBsz3SgFnW/tlhHt6BWsM42mDEaezMm8XrWh8OwDl2mu2ziTvQhxbMmo7bhBBFdT3c80@qzc9MbMG9gumE6iu2O9Y4hdY2hOTI9o8uGJiSyez4UAG112akxO7cdqFofpm0NZ5DQ6Jg9E5MEeABAvBLewOBwRvoMKtPyoBEwnbmAxtAIoCWFGMR/aLQnfWZPvPHEY4Bb13T19hCAtmesa/T0ydBLszaEATHJ/3xgWH6jBXAygDi2OVZfTAg1Y9629W6XZaC9Ah6nBjOBaoRWhWWz4M9sB6gGsQKMfGDUfnkZjSnUDVR5z66wfCYD4buhD2KrD13bR2YRNQy0oE9SnSHcZ47dd/QRUKNrEE0/3X/G3I7twBv8MC7vN7eB6ege29xk8d2nD@OsHlaL7LSFsIpq7AKqIBYEsjN9OIEWEq0JG@rHCVMLWGXxtXiFxYEsWoblciwH3bPEtDwQSc2UwQH9XMuq8CswrcRyKvSUfDyN@fQcvW8ODQ6lj1CK2MC1PNPgnsmxrFriMfv2sMejdSizIsuWWKHIinlWhHuZlTXIDUHnmFrOw68AP4BWBlRU@GVzHNC83UM7xba2w3r6yBzOfOgEvsPyKisCRMBXBchaCSDAM5vFXxZ@hNbiFYXtDYDaA/0MwEtD8xS5jhEyHqxCBR7KxoZCnA9ZK8/eHWD2QDogWr7EipB9ASiRAxSAslpJ44VwB8Zw6CcZuJiEMC1m4AdYF4EGJaB8BuiYQUIW4QfvwNM0YF4acCoNmI@mgr8G7iyCh3gFCCtANRZ8Wg109xQy4vloXSI8cG0AoyKlkVGpSCCAADXFslBfBZaDRpDFRpDPMsAdcCkWGPCqkspKOVYqMqBlOcOgXlTAC1uICjxSBXxUBAZ1r0Llq4CTCpRWAaiazTMhQmg1i@GQNgtpgSxqDtLkwA2VphbwB@mgVaiQpQp5alp53gABNy0P5c1nqWVqBajZIoQB3TTAVYOmpAG2WgnCMW0JaFjChluMpzkhdKQD1Ag2dWiDQIw84ENwIS64tWKW008fjgd62/DMDk/Z7mHSAnaBApIRkmawePDMITUBlQyAwR4A6GtQ@1nsKcKVAJ2WD8VRlgec4QV2d2RgyKSBQdnEfuftMGEFLCYJHHGRWwL7GkJ7hCGioyMrw45tEGMK4JiezCATGDcN@wzHeeIuC9m4xIHaDg7rMFx0DcdhGBdkATdNvMqdtF3j9QQHpDlePWB@BvDInm4OQwSoQ@oecVJ4xl3Ib7aIds@xR9RrR8iLhrY9XsH3gfOdI6BH9rkxR33OGPXxeAjDD/gbfPQDZM51ElBImonmyhGCRJiuMzABIGUFbNt0jA7R3i86pM4Cg19EscK0@r0sQnkQGZeybGwDz3YxjTUZDiswYBgdlq0rXeNMQR8@di2OWYhDMJrBmOSDaOsgXCDmhEUI6Z4m0zh5HNSsa48Wi8YZ1X5Y9IGJI8zwXJ9B7fWARxlTfQQiEEM5w4JRcQQthtcg1gQIeVisfda1rbgXQjl3QBqAQoclIYkDaeKZIwPERRuSYI3nCGlkk4RZewZNmaiVk0k@5JhcI5QsXCcU98hFPHhngXGzO@kg1TBv06IWBOONi8KSY@hd7id4Djs50eHnwMA49kViGR0Y8QhRi0huMKoaQH1fhOkQRBzsDcsFOcyVmYkCK7T8vt2DxnZuQtlBRIKkc9gdIgKSIPSayh1ZIJJjAxqdDpnJOuMxA38QPKB57mVKMJbbX5jsDQQOByCLdSaOM2PTMdSEOYJYXsfu9aD1vjHGAwDBRl3WmXWge0IlY@sRujZxos54sZjzt3UD4lgo3e08@zrrG0B2GPl7KM5jk58XYDymIhApdItLBZYOlMIidMYzIguACVP0bFtG/65tuNRYbOc07PqYmWv0qWtAP@vNmdEIpRxopRZJZ13gPH73QviYobC0MJiV3wo@NizoOh1oldDpofqwTrdZD7SSiCyAApve6Rhjz28nNrEz04oITgd7KDiRr@QDk92BsH6fbV5rNRA1bDkRoQAFSUR97MtzOvJaX/UBMcEy5rI75yzD2Y3sIcbZtdzFVxhnAYNX4gocxtQlUIokJjHxkJUgdzQ7A@SFHnIbElygtzmTm8UHv2j2zohJvTBvxEYFtiPISuiFeKyGIcFveBOQPB4irPqCB0Zd8LgDtO6OlkC2QySH3aivrOgyMMW7gI5sy14CFYgZwsUoiyFUF9QYj5Br6MOwMVJ3cRfqCBn2XBvHgQzG0PHYdqBncKYzI5WMqizSunxNJhGOFUnQ5BeHVhgy4jjgezgKQoLxEPQ36mLYU0FE1YFTABPjmgbwPJvnGEGYej3B8vE7J9bPGxOMpZZloJSrOzMOBIoHwzNkNGOm4wAbPMNBgo9BwWAiUzuFMQF0LuSsSA7q99czl7FF70za5vS6OtNBT/kLVzjTHdZDTcYBoQM6USLec@PJKvlTykiQqNhjT6Gk/C5CRIokQ5UneqAcwSCxB4zmaGZ1EuJCFxPTTJx4vZKYBAcm5DIa@6o@9q5j9wX4YaMZnUK/prcq68PwLUlwl9CPMMEARcYA3QE5AzohiOzlcrets0vgHqCWT3coNQqX9FTlXJiXYXXDvHxCIC7R8so8C9fpkEOKjGpYAoxOJadBYoGA70kJSiiCh6L4Yyt6kLTHw0iu4Z4TiyYuWIKLIkl2EQr5MAAkCBkThA@zY3otX1y5dy8QXNZqNWhsIE0B2@wmo@pBMMMjA6eGyDJJI34msmcfedg3EkkoL0a@4tiA2AQttVZnF97AgR5H71cCRAKyCha25ICwfj0/NU8n3esVbaEnRhKx14HQZHY8sSrA4M97Q@02qsYXqAoqRBypio0X0xPoG42XfLFCRT@aY7go/tZ8VCI1nEAM/La6lEQ8qe83b9A7s87QFwm4Czo750ZtQP/UnxEIGVHalwmCTnujp3Ig2B04HPZs@/hRze@LPFBpm1ZlwWNod/Qhea9jdDFI@3j/weH24ddbS2AMzXbluodi5koFHGonU6lvTZScrFXWozDmgB@2boeNCRfjiIIfzCR7GhGVZh0YXKYBOQ8OP7lOEpCEkByUA7jxd02k4XFA6BLauju4NgizfioFWYZJgrhM2mcBzNCBqGO4HuDzbPLmDVbedaTGvj9iNpzoHEDgqexbQToZA68JYEFQu8dHREoLUqhp4czs3BWNGeDzMUrN15EhUTrSZD4@2Ns9rBFYf5JCoiiK64EspTtdGdr8cNI1hGVxgP2Bq8NS8hxxlKcJ16UE7nQWCDyvW7YCPgBAXUe2mTQcBUVzB4D7zvWyka/UCVsAvROE63JlVB7qfCiiETxwiOugyrtsFKWA@WAVei0dscLQxWGrk88bxVw5Omx15nl2o0BpdhXGgUBudCDo1JXQR55Lkb5Y7aN/9PgG4i4JkaAKSAFm7pDJlJc7FFB7kUwWd5Ud0NDsoSG/II4nMjGpKPFgglXuuKR8RuLvTk0vkUnyp5qEuJD79va@9jCI7M/90UwGKQ2oi@PI5PRwQaTjQhux7KHdt9kGpOHSYZAhiE0ri7ndt60bNaSjJxY1hmsqwH9x4kYfw1hjviHFkVJF1VW@OqNb7jlwabWQRSIRhQiUQvHlL/QzHcg1L/fR/ue7MIio@UwmdGfoAhJE0hC50NWJ@JIHkyAj2cdnaQHD9ZUbvT0IkCILHFhon9GFCbfnwUs9iWPKytL4S1H6qn2D4l/Ys2tNC3x40wJHhGT7T5893n@6@2T7sxNPy@cX3nOZcgEIB/m1QRaSB5xu2Fs3eNfEYiG4GPQNB7sXcIEJKCjBtPvEdYBxyxhF5gisaDV8ZSrxVXtgxd3k9cKcY6j0hdXhTegJdj4e1U8IinZ3iMqIw5f3cDzH9jPwvLFbURTo5YNJWwalVfmiYw/1vkLpYGAYDhUVVZf9A5zXcJelAGTcmcFT8MktEB1mNIOoD0c2KC@0SIisgSU4eJq1Gpr9AejCuJJoOEk5bMFUGqULGgLoykpYNmLA9Aa09Z9BPYm8aX9F1Uq8XasZLaeIQbSF7g9x13oGqE4JGK2AFMlrr@zk3sk9NgMujZCuA4kxeYMmOVyGY8GQgSBJs6ao5wfEIW6B86XIK4hGryc4mwtcSslnckW1kFdALQM1DWRWCefcpJHudQaSZ0sAT7J7NG8QaYU9t6NbPXnDdwTIgtz3ERQ123h5cmI1QUA/uUe44QJeY9ZsqM1kld1MsuHHT1ah9S4UD9tu4AFtl5zQNOnJVvCzrn6TnXV16l1dpnijsT/mSGP2ZBsEqTc28OuuEe17mECJBiobC3EVjPxWWTIhNMSkAt6QUgp0KBhpoekpiJcEQi@Kh9BygG9FErD5bAYvB18Qj/ARVLqx3Zt23KUZf5RrcLbUHQMRabK5g1zaxflBD0bHsOUjl4bKRSbNzo04zqPrLp@thET@YmmQHnS1EALNyocz0la4DAyNgFKReg6cA9oVTpsO5rOMqPRDS4MMCSecfAAJwqLVgz7wGUjMC7LNC8JzIp/FIp1a9rmF0NoGK0lt0@OT/fbEwUVDsxstG0TPajwOQKPCRfg6rS62jQ6fZeWJqRSgBOpsZIxsnEoA6YpYgUFF0PnKJOqCLs5YQ7fKSLj8AvAldn8HuFjH4PNF0giVKGhSuyzuOcq29LmiS2@gNd8iW2Hht6NL61TpxwEBFteJaZbEnwEl6cQeUaQXNN@CgQ8CcVcYz7wBlBhamKjX7LFhXdf5uEaYSFZpPTceB4ZvWomL@NraWrwSr8fT4NoC1ya6ttCVAtcWuSRyYTwZXZQiTS4MbVAK9GvGrxoB5GmyiW1gipLDG3Oc0BuVSraZ1huq/9TwmYSqAMpDbAkfACeerNXQmUyK9XNcswH5PVL2HWw7Rx3HHPsk@CoIBPzdp0GWiADqPUrzjlFF3fR2ioxqDiiNBoqYCSd@0sicNE8uTrqpk6t4GlMnq3oN9ENgXl5iJPcdezIGwa2Rq0jA25KNbKVZbdfimfhGIlGShpCRnkx@VEqmdE7rRNyANpU4OYkDSX3qNDoDh@BN01oyGRIK8OiZoGUMh4m4fFGC/NvJZjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7p0kAguFRpnBHgj2jOnQEromDDERdcUiEHS4hR218@N8WDmRCOEs24gZeMM@nzRH/dGIBePcsk3PH1UoFvQ9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs84dxc4pifKwpaVYNw9k3oj29OVT2VQmuTIcBlfiyuSBCMhhXBIVOwnpotdWLcMe@JGZxqXToBi7uB7PJgAswz286ShVZljwegMbBZfvw/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDtyPBDJopSCS6WgHRBOzNM4Iu0p4VmZVRCgrOeYG4@Xxi/lsPcqpSGZTAjs2/ZjiEBSSCFQNtQaBOTUGf@Tph9mvm6sS7hh9KQhoq3aQBH3BvaOtGWs@vIetB4FEkP@jkkOTS6whD4Rw/Yo8zrwjG6yoZAq7S2M4ARAkqDnFgLa2vkByi2O@7K3hSSCgkccKOBXLsDofOcdTVNK3TyvUoQhq0CiD2ASkKt1AIVNwiSVAhM@pW8y6eFAh396cHDXT53QoMtDq84j9Ya2d0JyJW@3nRoWP0024X2ZFr2yAQyBOnfnA4PbdvjWj68rJqZ4UqzOZoMdZrzuT4tc2u6jt22hzQVdFvSefyJ4@pDnU9CBaHbnz4BWf/58VFNrkQiKfrZ6Na8cR5yebacnvvRNUdabw2Wh1zeMMX1vIjjVrBNDtmMH1DAgIm/SQ7qKPAvon/QpXANxfcvof8IN8iBrOzPItBr6OlHLFNE3DSHO4d8zws1c4X@K3WwMJ5K8bjgOMf2QtXI/8zr9Ra8s@R9KiFrGs69c@TNN88t6IhRlPI8Eu6kW4gTBVSgOOGGuuvxfOYV7jUYGMNgBfEQBBNcJYOxfYjiE@gmKInzPW8GCNJjXAwhDo1LbKwDsqZ7Y9oC@tRY4rGF2Br1ExjDFJRchHWF@VPcVeoplu0vTbqce9qg2tPsyWadL2aj6uRwrU3hk@/rLQCxWa8GG5RWRcOc4vEwGkEl3CAFFZPW728UNdyN4dKcukBJqoKrgNYw1TLSybS427yMKy6RocfEk5PpRxntM1A/cHfZ@j2lb1Qxw1X0qgYhcV9Ubc@YBIIdxuLz050BsBOWmi6SEupnYvXsYVfii2HQLhhXo7CC/L0I4a43f3OjYTrBhjfacciTIhuN7JW7AfdaldZvRojsrgsBQS@5YJen6bNL1oCR7Ux2x0PTa7Ir2bNbAySJN3Gs6/vwuKjpOPrMFfytLDW2ffjxp41Mk0MQRjoucJV4LU6D7ZwgH4M8hPtrwYUbcjzTowGfNhyYWF5VBqSmtBYC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULUL43LeVl6BiikCQMxd2ejNDOSV3JvqHueYfE2x1cZV5ObLwf52dQo@y1/baHCMrQAAwKoiWGAYpUdHT/cPTyUoeW6ifguLtRUoDvqnQHIIasKHVAyWvgK@6gbZx9hmiRq5wJ0NVAyWn56aNRVaPSgZkDuyCL6hpMAzySusXTAm5a1KCEXxHwC4baqjkc0CoEljCSUiYBVluL/3OIalY9nBVp8iigJ5E7cqwBtzaQ8sczXsgvjCYmnECXOdVIYFmrrCWJq62qSWo9jjnCFGBQpkg2hBI0Gk94A04PIIms2q3ypH@KinuX0kbqiSFVBu35ralD1NfAGyYUg@Mlrb9nLRkYqN1Pry0DRHjJ/wy4vfwQuQlgE7RpLs11PUH@/0ZE5DnzJjzPy56Q1X9uVXmHr3CHyqWWKHuyLIqZD26gWt0MtbraCToashGZcsCABS4j526n9NkvhxPlBtcFk5JFIsouQ6BqSnF1eEg3ZusaIhuBSGa@Mq0DJBMb02IbSPPa3UkeFAOqt/n4R7LMnghhoU4sLshjCJXXl7JoQKp2J0XRcCDStU5uWdUJXKyOreRT8wtSj0@HNlD3THdBtIWqIA4@rrcLOHbV7dFsSgVY3/HVz8qB5c1/kBVlRVw7pQVPoS3Je3CuykG3b6E2sPi0yoptJr@@IKZVLFLnXbpurogIRcPtX8FwSDZgUtmdNzslqsDcbZ1xgPALGxZWUedGvbzNiC3SH0cGDVP7zv36jC/S/WTsDGChwgjF0tGDoxpqSeisry0@KL3RbXrF8HnwyNHUiDLnuAtnRHSiSPgwdy0HTWrskwfA/wpUDv8ahbeINhMNbmhnHnC/8Bc/lmSxbO7OAZXZWxb227YpnRas8oL91iQhcCDINSkSsi1eCMeUrLRFNGtnY3UgFe6MYNWZe74OJN@F3kE/vrERzjL/b@qYfM5PX26oBGqLeNo1bqtzRTyddWxqf9kM5tbAk7rz0tNQrgTjgr/q20Lm8@LyAjtmHcTZ4roo2H9qUc3rc1Spca@KOpTYp213@Rh1hdEsOzpDfV0Ux/UNNoWM11cwh3d6zJfrQoaH4mx4U3FIqRYhmXiPzUG/PUAYZfHgrCzcQAMepdVKpTHbFCvJ4vDo9KoyUvlxennoqdzg9lk0FKHzbqsQny6jA/kbWO2oVhitzpA8lrRtxrmTmy/Yf3IgaLl1SGuMMF27OltbcnPo4IHUmQ92Zu25p4nM8gtWCVRPP/rDxzOzYIA6MmVqUVS0YOiIDBrHMYAfcPCPcNUy3yC4HcxkZu6AW4iAuha7lLMDueLgzdEWbeg@Gxndk4r7XSCOR7VWU6tjn@FspPgxANeX35SPam6VYvQdzkoadoQ7j@MrhYGEOEOcY72io56Zr0G05YU@XIup1hkv9F7tAMLsXna27q1m75tB22RHdbyNQ3wEq8PvyBh2lpalbEs15R9238KBgK8O8QvVh3x4WSn1Fh9vKWp84PeT7/vN9OVzIoVT1Dg4ViD@2pfrPlXz9VHFO76ogOuDl4DbWiPOWIXYZm/KXWFaXDhQDXJ9bXrK9TIlSygqf0VuRMa6snOuz4Pl3GDpWkTYYOsYzEqdBusME5RI4PIeL2H@X3HK359Z9P6Z0A2zxrkJEKvd0aMBgRfcbVcq0jPqBKdRM5v1ZVG84MSbGUkXjoP2FgceNb1Ey3h@pjF@MdX9CHtcA8ARKGOuNrxm@F9Y4TuPbrcxEH5od425RZpGpjUH6HqPq/Awcz9BxM0XfmowXanVBO7MObyfZYBx0abu7gB2GfCgfKt0hKS3I565Bv1s1Jq7h4T6wWi6TyfgCTGRhZeHlNk0qG6b9wuT3hYzJZ57zPC4upjkR5/I8iCzRnYYrWZC2SrGnyOWyYpmW4c3w/p7ctG3bww@pKWCqXRNFMZAsaUftbTV2Q9zxz4qw@dSFixMe7d6qSQs@2vi6JdAHlebbKj268vNetSnh2uYI150WX2@fvomsI92VC57Txjkhvsd2uFqW9GdDVLkkF2/tdVxCtdvGUOePaSF3G7yynL0V3iLT8NdkcQ2Xr9zOV9xj15jSeAbEMrugpQyMkUGvt0j5ehdNCviPlZGmNv5WBU8No6NMd43OqghjE/iChfeFpeKIsOTZFuhXHm7nQz1liBtGfd9VHDhY3FtK5P2R3je4LYvbOOV8wgI3zXC1bu5cPnVR4RtlOpBsbrxgdZOATnVqzNzguRTgk1kH6nUyunu67Vrn7@Ac6Hv09lU7VW8OsdbAHlgDY8C3h4dvqzoHtEeP2x65DXXAuj/AHWvj8cJO9ig9h/Zw@D70RNbIGaVt95bitItnXPGA1gfBneltCPAfd07e6R7nHehY2WsGxgTGJdf27LEh0duqqEOc6OH3VTw0WIv@u84g3arnA0WC598V/p26ZV@3vfGYHq3xcOLSjZJKdDT5Lrmpx3eg0N5H2@nLb@xRW/Y9ZX97Ci2BL2cxbdPrDPBsOG/ZRt9udwbmXUi3Dd2zzFMlmPLhr@@luyJlTCY9RG95aAJ5nZmM7aUWDT/Cx/6qSvdnj/iwFjpukVeWzdDR6WtprJ92XD4bii5WwQnhSG/kZ7QrdMq98npienOgkS1L4fQuX5ZAxyrc/U0SKyUrOgoxZ8P@5omVrZSEdBTIJSMDAo@6KtvF7WyRLpbN8tsqhKKlJIwi208@hNz@Fh@aHTQj87bgv9C@FvYmLR3krMGk795kmHy6vgsiGt5WT1vQluXIlDWMWbrlP1aRWRsqeJYRni2QuSbGrWsq@VsXVSieOpR024RHCx5QdZOVc2hDc@zyO5N6K5fi/C1LoItfXy/ktJktV6b9iukaPb4Egq67RMSR7eCGY5BBpA6upOMMOjJzLnhxxmXZfWDq0pDNIwdxV4ktS3cDLa/@cMyUPntq9HXcUv3Y9HBP5pJWQU122S6iO2F/baK75tcmULJVjQ0NM/BlSCd6gh/flsB7ovfNzqOFigiR9Ansb@jkj4Xmj1436@J8YLq4oyl03DIxhU2ON2JsdS3QG5bEvD5vH9qkmHcgftpxaexlc@v2eIaHwmbkum1a3fRoltV/rlIdV@31uhWJ88loPHH9x3IcaM9UdBZ6dEr@7rkJwKXXwFrZQB96y2eqI1OuIIX5g@LcuUoa/9wc2n32eSnDQGgDIQyF8yUN5wEMz89wQ45jLWmJlPd7LnviRIfk8IK9hro1skwyLdO7fTbH83BzTvDEwvCRAw8iKI/xLt//UAjS8XKKPL5b1p@fQL5jfIeWd2RPnI6BztCsSFQt8HM1doJNxnhww0azKOdRLa1jD6F7gWO4tMt0bGviSc7EunVUKNw6KlTYtFSINAOW@Nruk@fJaGugTdl3SaEGKH8Tdzibu1ZuGLjWyEwLBLHVfHQxdqBLPOTmkA5pR/AdabbRZlOH2PVDe5m@82wGA8h7K0zA/Cejh0YHlw3vzPup/cS2bBiNxsAoR4cGP9q/sNFjeUJM9hgPrwN9undmc0RgVwxCXNrQx0Yb6nc4d73PWMQBP9Q9fcVQRHODpP@FrjvbijlsG84XNOkXca9SaRcRemRMSbdY3WB4H5S8ToeLxDgft9BHFlZs3LFtW/xO3DYDD/XJ7VwFhgK6vf9CuYz77RfmBZbqZ4tFPTjju0SMLrc9saqsjtG2h/x@y54ky@R7AnTHNFzlMZoyIL9Cjkkgfbm38pDirTxkrhqBJHumu7RIv1zVmINUpx@wBWigOx0bV8J8xy27cyL2B@5g0@EWfr5xoA2EnwLH0jsT37jiXWgNR@0R3VYqDJHaPDTaePinTUY7PH16szL5zJBvsSCyoys85x@wK@zUBZZ4BtpI8u5ha0GPWqSqOaYbceqVy@W0WUeyTKPzRsdZM5voNZ@bXgiHMitPyblirjrSjWgWWdHpQPvSnrS4dQ0EmqEheQMHdH7Fu216O7CmsmQ9ZDIycJF5cRVmpehquwMqrL18PT1kro4h@Sb9gJeE5v24fChtr5Q8ETz8Hzz4qgKDcKuQCyyMAOu6ewUfkJ84lv94nxb4zHa9njk9ALzxFMAqdoLFykMSePCega6NVYWA2rMmQz770I/suxp1SR2TyGqtJA2JXXuGZFhnEtl7m94skc3PdinbaO3UM7qSb@4AVxqkx8ExrzCa/1yygBrljbjZU1U4YaeFnL/9cxlxzwPOAPKW7Uljl57K2H22//jgWB676tLxaXuApyNuyHEL9hO0UiYyJfWF7kTWO/l2tK7pesqDI1XaebwvY4QV9OYrGhI8cGVu4bFy3tM3J6or@kotCEMNb7mA@Oj4yePU/CQmS@wMHHtkJKPBO0dHaTxp8tWjpcHR1HvQO3r2dGXy/V1VTS5pvs8tWh1cxT2X5LQK0rEB2ig0xkfc/MqdwlXHHhvd49nY@BQGT@Tg7ntmX1hZyKf6mdnHXsjKKwlFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcq24YTPVfV5ao6RW3boofDHyu0oKDlkFSe7XHq4bcX/uhTDMv5OhA9LpGZutlbPlKBn9AfoUnT374uYqqqr6Hyk96BeWX5lZS1GWLY@PLTP3mMp2fCVFyn0kjxoVZJ55z7yojQC1q3gDafnfU9wtldug7kNQOhdWNrhzw1rplsSrWXdJl5UIDVuars1yufGeyxIhTt8ztDA89I1vnBLPUt0yJm8I@NjJ5JkZ@fB/l0JDn1a3h7r46fP2TPdRVsjt0eMYmy8B8ZzyegLCeet0NDdyuXUrgOgtFvh9cfL@3OFHelO17Zm07sX4eioKQ7tZEM4hIVvFMkYmlNz2VjV4fNaz5ZvM7orb36Iw54tyMFRGzQ@oHff/heqmsmQhSF8qhn@ekfNBB2cJdClz9BsXTToeD9kDR2UW2TwSC7VRh8bU9yOwmeDlyn1S8e3wi1jXzG5eji5Lax0S1julvxuhKEny8oZ9RaA@VvCWF4Ogx/bw/OBLe/ojuEu2X@8FKHbClK@pSDlCHd@U8rgJCgtLPru1SI@Hl3wH0tb67HhObnxwG6buaVl2O6hLUn2BG2i3wz3t1PoDm1v6dv@kQ/@vjy/84mxNKMn@pvlAcRpTpcGARM0BhM6EnEzeHGBtA0yr2H1TW5GkT2wvV16W4rkMxt3rC/N8qE5fjgZr0YUWCJa77/OxRcivgBV2T532QM8ETeXzpeo/Lgtbrn/KlGWhfOBaET00fF20KgOjhQtkuMci8@eLXjjmVHv4Cji5xjT6SpdV5quUh2XhsxzfXqcW8h2s/7y7Cax@PG/w4kVtRDtpn0bH/y4LD@k6MqBGe9EwkqlksnFj09ET1yiHdXEOtoRXKfTlRD38pKt@ScaIUAMzkj6ZzjR3BhoWAYewhQIhFdbh2xqNTVfZlv4xYcKyE9JyhG9yKhTkFeDrV/4xxMrFfWKrdWYWBGZf0A0tNHK7YwCXLSQCGVi0qnK1j0IWQ8ONzIymc8uGelkIASq@Qy8yUr0mHfVP/4JKK1fPNt/tnt0vH38/KiRaV75x0ODQlgW5BYcQv8o2xWh7D7ZgNdzq8N0LHkI2ZE5f9Tl3KBcDEp2rWi1haLNCyVuYZr1C8tSFDohq0hXgJ8k8twoFAQ39OKwgxJT/fiHoyv8sCqduYUq4qBFyhPqrMIyyzIe68C31i0//PqnSSgUP11TwY/XYMa@oVhoiH3b7vo5uga7@wpy3Nvef/z8cJcFCM4bzbnZ9Qa1cp7bEean9qGeeiZtGaqxuJ8kDnVVq8X34kCYuBxnFTrTTDZ8oZ1DtIA6eBraT73BEusEHygYDytF@a/fUK7iMu5@TULceIBUHLKFJk8NZW1tjR1DI2EPD/c/3T1kiP/uQ/JGEiEIdowHKv/0x11uBT@waxJ8tscZEbch@xFC9FB1cNJ4fhgaaU5dd7z64z1kdZ6OHIfm7sPvdQgCfQ0B2u05mSS7Zq4qSRZk@MeGfGtiQUbUhALL2TjRipbBHJedma6JB54Rhx4a6lps7Lg3g4zTyWwbv0yE3z/S6ZMMgPrE8rgxHN90RgxamhyynDRbJ2T5BxzESMT45ho09rYB4w9zLdBeDa/CvoCWiJOZFX4gXpLq8RtJAtAVckkDbzSMRLxh2ctVThzl3a/8M6VfZeD2wP0d3z3NPIC3X/LfeuD@Ze5@qWBDu2kJbI5LFCG03ueXgCMS0h9pH/kgk8WNEMwJhwbLAr7KzBFU0xlRHaPzHPhdAnY8h5NofAqVBs0Nasw3PsDzM5xmAs0HVhQFmxTKRDJt/TamfB/WNTOChXwhpyqApHQWACS73308YMoBJpMV6CbCmTmuvYIBd3Nzk4moGBm1QpXXrLJuvcyKr0JE1yGucD5A5BoM0kCSeQoIq/vJYPBJqUlMitwrrsaRcXVtGJUoHEcvfLd8QogsAcTiNDLQkPQUv93lObPAHGYbv3YV@SbEug9IUmFMIldSFPxj@09tD5oPdNL5V1/4sX3ch8hHQLQz5/Iv15EVSmyP8s2eNT9tGnx8wu9rMvIADiqbuT6YRutWfIEgjhBERVzWfBsv2Yl3YjUV3jYZNNMfLmnMFrh/UemvaLO83Ns3bRAmrlsQRGKx@0eWjRrgHhSGJTRFyypqITkvUi63tEh@ifxsoDhoAeUSsgM2BSyjY5hf2GN3e2d3/6sHz45u2NmjmPHr0YDv1zdTJ5KcbjRDRzxarMUqebCnHD15sBdUxBzpQoQbA@P3S6LeVpL5xA6CnB8UuF60ZRheL91qjF/wo8TX8c1qt6FGiW7goWY@IF/arCvt0ZGb65lrpWXUyudvQ2kOT4mA3uHnJW@gmkheXDWam/UTKxa/2RKWdISXMXkDOwG4TtyNdQUb@83CYcHCb0oe48en3GhfzC7vi@J6Fs094XFtzz6dG7ryPSIBkfIG2QCLFGQliLqy9x1wGX1ujk3j37zkhqGiZm8iCBcyt1E8Auo4@HwmcpG5MUnfjuJAdwdDsy0E5oa4PcXA7FtoSpGbCkokBf@TBDzjhP9BzWllKtPOnEQSuR3BSrPbTDMG8JICdGiU7p5NQMd7Zo@5iWpagX1oBK5DG9gvKJakuhnsq5MRxOvR49Cg2XDg3BIkBkrGQ1S5LAVcwrfMOE2h7UvIr4H2Gf2Cy6NuPjFNygNj2jX7wNsTyTRwtI9UtclC641YaLLWaMVFqrN5LdzaFT/GU7BRsn@QCc/pHAG9ocugGhrTRPw8nqw0IX/0j5@/OIsnxWVtiUyJ@rY1u9dtioboF9XbOYnu@b0zMNi5jFuUyze5BPhdB8yNXgXfxymX5YEr0PfOaii5H3nOY3CCGJHojfQxS0wsbjBMZvSaOElYabKkJNW5zUGLpVKkUMGDAmRGKXvk4uN3QrdmLKHUoBGgr2t18fHGHLOGKstNcFMmSbaO363aAYkLLeUlBdCBIUmFwNawCYGaARjxTiLzBg5pMBziwoPMri0Jps/40KShjTShUrP6PRb5Dtmi5CiWyxW/Qhe5YplB67vJDmUFwN7gc4FcD9T1bYkAzUD9lYXYnJHf5HgxyjfGEXnkGyEBdGIRO6GBbRIGsOZWPDsDB3@JXQv6CsgHlcrz471WKamILDRm0nfMLk5qc1PXoYrnf5wEuqmyEDVe5Rrdx5gMzca1uLUUtF62Rx1GvMZSY1EyXP9M8Lxtquqtrd5P6NcCxMzhAOAf@moF4NA@YrC9YEnYcmb/s5/hh4jFxLqqnracs1Q8n6nCTa3mWZ59tH4iSeuNTO3@ug5alPd6egI6ubKRe3hmDHrt/b5yIoosy3KKshHf23hmaoWXr6dXWbX0@nSsFhry62lTLNXSp0327Nlnb1tvk@L0bPZaPEmQ6Sq2c3ApqjlU82OVMrvYKmRjp2X84iT85VGteUOa@il7A9dpj@E/ud90I24d3e0exhXjIoudnOAHhsWiqCiNeBP@CcgruLji36jLdXmr@fZtsqHr3nTGTNMcu90u/OwBSJBa8gij3QNOT/EVdhKdNxhNewvzCHqe1TU8/yffb@E72R@cbhv9/mRXn5mTPe/J5y@C6zlebw6XTkg0U6mEJDWue1daej7GtIz2pz9Zu0pfPGtt/uk3R4qxho8DfHzn6gm6j9T8R2trHz14kMulNU3j7mefP/v69vZ27mE6/6yR38pJmbXNP/njtTVN29SUtabrqs144/T0M1HL5ET5T38Ubz179jXXrWf/j2@8rat4K8LtjBWBT8CVZSo48V6Cn4oyFiO98u4r9iYGrVyNzeivFQsD1pha3yr@t@8dvI55sbqmvHDg6cVexwqlGHeCA96ywdtZrB7bxGiFq9hMqdVq4Cz@t38P6etfBTgYMtuEWz0fwCrMYnWpRkkuY/UCOFRNg3z/r298I4IhZxM1EuOC6z5rwCXmipq41YRrg65NAY3ESRlFCeJZ3sAzbKaW7qn38MWEF3hYBhrVNryTGH7BlR3cZ@ywkUqlmnJLgkt@Se1LVbUTVR3fA3YgfbRRq0kbjJvBy2bz99Bib5KmtPo2jJjGvRf/GFdsmWf1A4EcCrHC2v1XD@t1KEm2nt2op@ia9x@FFUuibd8XWZq9ioPi0Wi@esx7DKuLmZImptNp3o2mSCBpOm8/9KX3GL9CH4bu634LSSCK7xv78HixXbz@7H/9s@//2ffo7/v0@09oO8/qmj1lAyKdQUeow3W/UunU62LdES9O8L0OrSdTKVVKSuvqJLEBfKd5yNTMx5fxfDYOLEalP3aSpNRwUbZ1P3t8r8fm3nXuU4/6@QE8MnkwvxTkWKAauUOq3YgHA6q/y1BqnNWbEopBNamhFvJNiacKsKyXWeM@VJOoFctis67ltQOoOlXkFTdYd5kdA32wENDRx7c@L1s9DJm/1aNesXqQrD6P86HxAnTrQqzRUJoGDQOBH7u/VlkrVQoVTWmFnjcvVr3pZRjGMzd2FgsvTp3YnKCxsGle9wuqInxhQQtmHxJPiEnvM8P9QRdA34JrDf7oH67wFe9r5ON7U5Sb1xqrqBtaVsl/VNjVPjB/AYYH1mm32286bRj/db2td3TV0yf6VJ/pXnvSnra9zgQN37x/mYTY28YaO@RsqMlSwXWSuvN6Lsst30kOG3@SZE9jQuwf4aqrmso2YFjKwA1kMXKCqox/qiqw2AVczbcbjbcb0EPrqU1ij8265GMJD7l1v5mSrq4a4K5W/f/Neuis0sVdULjmVSq1@bIOEsfLeiMFIF/6IGUOU27Vm5sUEOblZ@YHbzZBZJFSm43Nmr1DP0gCl9QEgJsLSN6/n5LBdR9S1tebLJ6z4wX7PkumUuuStIYjYsMfKyBNs54KCoU4JEDE2IR@d7V5Vb9qbF5dbW7C/ybdr/wn@F5t3vinx/xaEWce3mSNrFZqIpc4aSj1E@XE7/NNeJeVOvrIygk46vCEeCAaCLENthFDo2bZ2IYQe/Xuy/8Zfyfvvvw9FJgY/BkVIXaBDVzZQHWrzLUuuDHricWe8MsCN/6CV/RBjyd19LT4zcIVGUV5JbMKn/ROqKVCUsaxqGX3WnhOWmavICpDBs1ErVQQWyl1prHYplgoEov@@RtXPB7/J6@0cjHOZyfwcO8r13WfRDCb4waRq1pGldTLOrdfzb8o8PPLrn/y86suIXZZZkYFaNJxGaeGEIMqiEkSsOv65gg3f@LygISa2FntM@n5toRTB7pHiz8drhbX9ndr5XKdr2ysP6M2s/FwA@4q/O@uQSmEWPs1/j1@g3/suIN/h6/xjx2/wb9DD//Ykzb@Hb/Gv@02/h2P8O/Ba/x74uHf8z7@nfxcNqtWxfULIkBKLatX61ORCFGNbdVPfo5XTS/@0@9@85vxWi0uxelTBjnVdpiarAIJXTdevR8XYjW2rq6rmWGmk1HbahscJss4LDPIDNQuSActlWUMlpllZiwzstUuuAz4y4DLzPRYps8yVsaCiBAKLq@V8dDVg0cf/noAyIE/EzcktdVMh0FGQxTD6RtoCB5cl60TocHiTHxlgI4kq3JGLphN/HJEQ3z16kTZaGrlEpOxXcitxquTeBNtDGvlHGvPjLWTVyzmgpJVjSknJwqfLoKyEjmurlqt3acPWy0FeebJE/tg/n9wMIq@3vo/OrCfHNgjG/4PDg6eMGbUU/dTwFXu368Bl/EfW7F6deukQkwqYFQxZXPrpJ6V0F1IAQvS0C/1gdccIjzraydC/DyB8vE5isjVF@fVsyq5z4NXcLSq8whBNO7wn3CdAz8OhOdzuM7O0UFv6Dx/cRK6uEN5cQ5eLxjoBuE/KCHR13@Af/P/Xf9PnrMkSzSaycTF1WaCriT@JZMXVxdX/r2eTCT8l8Qm/KEHvGOSi6s6OinSBbgaiWQzeXXF/eCeSG5ygHXIZrNOaefxgHPHwiwpW35L/MM@IWv/OolXmT7f6HFyMs1kktV2YBodly31S1pNT1bp81fr7Yba/JMfkfn7rSRFyueqVXWD8Rctp1WrueCtWKpWS8HLeiJRvnnVM1tqAUTjXC6ZrFbhZSsAm4HXEGwJwAYveYBquHrH54IX@wdkGB64RD6GX2TgbCGRoc9K4BeK4mJFvHcv4X/5eGs7ee@eVs5cXoY@4zF4qQterVbXdFot9M9eXootkfZdlPPwnildXqqZckqNJ20n8RQ/bQVZJSSVfaTVKdcyMF8tV0z@w0jLACy/uVnI1euFHLgLJVwBvnkRNZi4Ho9dBON1MclZY3xdEatc@YLe7eLFLq5iVO0sl08mgLkmQea7iuEf91bLZe6fZLlCopQq@3@1NdAhQQ7hfzhjkU3lNoob90FCw7/p0gt5cvXCqKlXtQujgjO/V9WO/2FRPJBt3LuXLQNZS5nqidBqPdw@3m61aqIooiwDN/Qk7i7g98zGTrxBVZ4vNxtYwuZJPF6p3qfmoZbyDNqBH0@KwzDBSmUihGD20NoClF5Q/fmgNUGjJ96Esj9LBJ4geWPW@OvCxbqszfp4sT7O4TGTDeliQ8bD6d7phJFsfvmh4SulxSv0McJLiD17vL2ze5zWNiUW0/a2d9La0fMHMRVf8/N3Cs7i@@Hu9sOD55Dg2ePd7aPdj/c/3X3@DPxddj6/Aj7v3@fPqGvJ@zl7IXzhvNENQzcmhtE6n0zOX7MvTLNlQv0NJ1AIu@8w12gB7mN9Xo4q/Dqmq3/xhe6M6WLvfvjtdz/879799nff/fa33/3293/65fe/Db8fw@@7/Pndf1fO4/2nX/6L33n3W78Nnv8Jfn8Iv5/89Mtf/wb/0fsfwe@/RPz@yP9F4vGfALB@6adffu9HP/3yl38Av3/l/35w8/crP1n@@/63Vv8w3fd@5/Y43/338PtdDiuI@93f4n74vBH/t3i8X/7Bu1/7D/z/T/w/dP72u1/7I7z5L//8B3/yX9598z9qWulP/u27b33v3be@@e5b33n3rX@qvfv1f6tmorffeff93//LP/jdv/yD/5H@f0z3332f/3c/@Od//r/8@f/253/g/34Cv/8Arp/8@X@EvvE3v/9D/P/e7//NH/4Q//@nf/03v/@rf/NL/4Ycv8Ed//e/@nf8/le/8p//@je/85c/@cZf/@pP/vo3fv8v//df/j9//T//1X//e3/1z76Jnr/xk7/8w1/6i29@@y@@9S//4ptfrrh/@9b7l@/h/@U/gs/74/k@cN6nXB/q8@XfCZ@/DzXmuUA7gdb9i@9@/Reggf8aY@@@/WM8vQC/Ff8/1lSK82P@9v8Bh3azzBiSARf8fvXdt7@LJPofgETwH9LrO@HLQgh/@c78Bcj6m0sS/eJPv/yXP6K3mFGp02ICDtclrZTaAJVmo1z2h2x/nQGS/MIitBCAn9N3kEMthH0Hedu7H37j3Y/@6bsf/sa7H/4SDphSrpzeTkvqnRNmUv494mHEwvvEw4ifYf4pmgqSUp/BG/vMD/zss8@E1qWCx2TuX4LvZ@TFL8aD8BiNHxSEoT@eq2GXLOr2nRnfue77hjkTFphrigSNjUAKymfZNOUjNGV8wQH9IdJ0g5xTvJMvBk8FvM3/586pwFIYh1/4Oa/ASQ4/nZ8Fdwp5yCY1DZc5SCxjXBTa4D60bEn55soMSzCdpqag74IDckhB0IMUq9VqKUxY4/jAK0etXmKESipVg3Jjap4m3SohiOkDggIpa6lD1tqoTXnCFMKrB@RICeh1KKqamCrVHkKGtelDhrAQOIF99apWL9WmdQT3ltMjNU09IJwQWC01rb@F9xrBhHRC7OFbQKVUS6XqJcwQC8mrJ93ilZSnwlHZUyzl1wE8cff51n3GPhLVktji0iESjMfGe2oeGyNCdAg/SW34xaH/wEm/DSL4GmXl58J4@BYJoltcNsUIAFeSZFlm8MOFzy12H4KnHFSKsoVHikNIUYugFhB6MJz2SQkpqt8UvUD@sdrGB18IDAuzvr4uxOpiVjyQiXSKwpzTCm3Fx91pqHhUmFgoi@ht0LmEABdIX6X81@O44hNnHDD7KMV/9@9vsI@gmPSc@wlMSmXtnB3jUDZTKVED@HU7JbwEDUSAdkqALgV5WiMlJyWk04zJtRiGsYODAx8J8nhZE1LQzLWsiu@4zjGZTGKQQpbTcjrtP2V6kofsO2QK9Z/yOhKXPg3LNC1XBUWpytCLRbUaFRRg9Hz79i3UCm33qeyDbsr8nT9arkSB4MGtBAyHs@D8ipYrC1wvZ2ohx1iCJj/hSrKkwBJsIynwTeIcieBKxLVSKU7xgPpyYiPYCFZQqTngxGesjogGF1cWS/lkELhzwHYOnjzZfXo8bjaZYNCnbo3W2LE7husmMGz76UN@QEArF5KxRgNBH1c0ZDDCbiVD7G//4eH@UYXxQvtVkCDEqrTg5xezrAqx8fjFZszfCCPiZ5xs8QjvlXnZElo5C0ljdSHWMVCjwJXcKm2BqApP3P4Dewoqf1oU02oB1bgkTfcy4ev2hKGRQW6RAPoUHhuQNzeJAkL9QqLpeHRCbRWEet3fQsZUoX60ewwJjg@YqmVkof4Zm8qYoXQl1Ie1oWH1vcE67sUSTzJipEzrjUwa/7RsFu5qrpBW88Xm2trwQsI8T6jaLnBT3RW8XkhYjK/AxYSvCOwr4AUX5IE75Zi/TXH/oOrvFUNzPgm@YUxU89DNksIJVDQHJ4yjV3UMzRu0@shPiK19/rnH6nXQpaX9PSEG7GLAgv1SktmVBzLVc3fiGBTaZ6xrfmriB7rkrumOh/oM@g6QI3Z1ddUDSPt7TKtr9MpTdPF@1SGfNrivproQsyqV2ls1VxS000rlbVbTBPAQNhTckLUGLYBWuDcU/ld1IZNstqQAq1JFER7ZbFbAOWGhYgiMti68zdRqEm@D2ZxKOxdwakDRpzUtvPy404/mcbMZHhdDIID1PYdlgrAiD/PfCgK9xdZwrxZ9X7Tq983MvXtZnK7I5jLhvMT/fy25aI1lc1zPZtRNZQxOHZy5TUUHZxuc@U2lDU4TnOVNxQTnpJ5VM5vKpC4wYZOb8mNoKaAmesYULYdyP7HuGsOejIdcaiJloImbvmncup@ujqeFbL1bw@PkeLIjkbwQ@rVzOmQoGLW@jFYJHEsfCt1a1@7Qd4KFrty2uzPZ9WZDPBcytJ1aHCS9eBBg4tec8TBlzQBRA2eytrLZXKXBmvLYHm8JWr6YaqgZGCPwp5bSWnrN2CoWK125MzR0ZytfyZfSXTxy4q8wbeUzlb782ZPHjzxvfGjQOZStXBkSoEkfNL6xVark881GQxRTDcqmiZ8v5RxIWluDXmvoXQmePdvyXEkrNSFx13RqtXh8K6tqklrJZkrCVUghAWiLBawLmDKFBUsjfS/8Ll6xbAvYSSWtp80LIkKl1@tdbVyk5i@CfiHxNyDPlaSn2xfha1WKxKuwSVoy54Hgo/eA8Bf@ylpF1PIlsdqozt@LBbHavBLuj4yuqePpk5PMxc1UBWC7HGoMMjphwlXFsW2v0jZ6tmPMI2bVQhCRI3QzQk68CrM7yWCOFzezK2AkoCGnHDRmbluxTjsuG2o519wFhtFobgZWF7ERx16@1PV6HSrsIlfUcvlcXssWCvmiBgNDOVfIl6BvZAqZvKYBgFy5VC5esQSMXrou1WtZLStomqRlpawqqVn8v8Oh4f/7x9fgX8M7pMpqwjGaLngKIw6MkhZ7jEegPZsd2/gRjD57YHRWxNgZ6LQ3dcexXffvEeeBbp3yoIcmtxcYBj3S8UtA7sj0BitiPB@P0OqB4fyjQdgdtQFBYhMU4QHcnKFtL4tQZM@frSjlk9BCLxCDm@iF6If7Hz86jjyPd7d3HgkF9uDg6cNrj7wfKc8e7@4dh69FHhokzYcgvr77@PH1V/@RO3h@2JvYDv6EvYPnufkt9MKjj0IOrsVIoTcB8W/4SjIZzr@vsXwxcKgCbpi/B3rlPd@ZL8ydGXS@4Oc6TTfcwM2P@FaE4@Cwp86Qg7UN1uHGLVDRJcNTvhisFsuCMGaWfc6KGda1h0MdP2vcWwPPgY4H1wyUBYf0VW7M@tx2ht1zs2usCU/wjFxZxU/IIhLCIwAymnTIygvIAWjGsIsfHMYFn/ZwYrAJfux7hSc80AudjtkfwCB2bgcRhLauM/h96AXpjejl3e7h8TzI70bI8GZ0ISaI4iPd06f3Y6Vqp1rPVCr37qnPHLGcFd2@sTuF5sqeQ/fRnVm6lBc9WdxjcivWNxtVtzmGKiuop/lKzh7X9TqI8Q0QemFc3MppQNl6KZP/q9/88d/@8a@yUlnr19SNk/hJZicDAyh0IRDIUBpkJPD5QqFM@oFWLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLg2pVLIN0nVFLaqGUL6vpUq6chdZXhtB8ueiLlEogQyobFQBrdfADp5ukYsgD0CX4ch97k9CTLKaH7xMmGpBGFFCb8@hI8IZZg3GKqRmWLTKAqLMOi@3t7WT29kTxAb7gNoedjCh28SVfymSKD0TRoJCdEgooos3TlNBUlOjxl0zmwY4oTjgAtLIsigN82S3gfJQomviys723h/n08EXD9BDtlIfwl2HwUoRoFr6AqEsAXofQINo2zydHiO7iC2aJIXs8ZAfCRPHjAB0MOeTROIBHQUm3t0Vxn79sb2PIDhU7zxH9BF@26RJFB16gI4hiHxx9B7qgKLbBid1BFDvg6sx08MOPyaIhXsvTRXHGyYMEEsUpxdY7p6LYCvwxm099bPJI3Qq9qLzU9@mljH@iqAVIY7Rs@JIVxVz4koOyPXr0qT7wukafXzOHPztQ0kePsro5nezutT/@uN3vt53Z9u7Hhxi0s/MIRIXZxGn3237CdgsuG1LtPNL009Hs@gWl3m@1KvpwadAnrVZOt64FtWYtAzGEVK8BM//qY0aj1g4E7Txq3deXLb0SwBZyghE823g9GMHzgd7mQcFFQfSctttiFZs/St70iXfoifS19fRI7zh2Fd@ntTXG4ol4etYoZJpVCmAjkLEz1Sv6tnsC7zrOnyQvZo1pLdOsTWtFjW/b6SXEk6mWN8X02mhLLecra/qWquVS0woaJLB7cRaX1C2WUO9tvGGJp8ktDYRs8WRrSxIbanNLU0uVQvHlxkQUkxW8b2WLFYiYiWcYw1uyUWxuFfORJMViSle0SrGYrF4BPTwY2ts4r9FKJM4N/TSZRHRRy4Yi8C/Lz6icZrWXmKanNY4XmyWr05pa5bYnWeYGrC4aOp50PNvhEPsAbrqVqdC360W1XBIhf0VJJJOo/ZJ6qwjzjYEvvnZ8enz8GXBCJtR97f8Z/y5z1X/9@NGOvH8QvKGBYnkPNRzbkXeQXS2EcPu5gdcxyPjyIxhLQd0J/PDYl2MP5d1pxxijmhQEBGYnZd9YoHz8aAHO0cA@5znjqfkqWZyyOgZD@81ml@m1Orj0LksQVkxPntMo3qrXa63aiA6WQxGDVJ8wMm48B7PvctzDs/yU/AKPQvkBrVrmqtquTWNTgNOqMUl9NbK7r7RUp9pFs80Pag8wcbUFz3bVqBmOYztiTKz2tqwaYxPL1XvGM8NBKxX7B@sgU@D5qESPGcl1drKLsXdQE7iS6g6z5pg9nYwSIJ23k4tekVckTeJrQZEv6MAebme4qvZqLPEyWX0Nr846S3TlB8mtXLWbeMBaSfDJvOq96jGNFXJV@p5qAiFBJyLaYJn1ZK3@CYhBHPBppQKI@HV8CjAxJwBrdilAT47Nq2qnNmQJiU1ZksiTq/ZrDUx9ibdNSRSbktS4bAp1SXoh1KGfVmcxveZO2mTrn2XaqpYpVKfgpxZz1QFUrP5yWnVq44ljVIfw6k@F8XOJehXICVQDMG8uE@9@4RvJTSlf435VAnU5BMmjJbdq06qF1sOgSdSyNQhINXKZNCjHcCumYZjXCmm1kM6mc2mpiL4wxqfzafAEJQdEi8QwITImpjPTjKymVUNNJzKvzO6rZPo0AaILkYwl0569a01GDHygkrBV0is8dZZMaRtDBrVgM31TomYKnKKKBQOaD9jYTA8Q1KGhDylFMimx7EZiuJ7AOOvHk/Fuo1mp7E7HX4OghPR6q5AqZlJvkslqYi1Zc43XQr0q1JGrUKnHa9Bm/VlC5k5GDahjcKlFrdJotLGIxUw6m8lC6czWZX9TrIvNdGatoEIVXTESjxjnGNF5MxRy5n7jFgrfQwOqTi1rVUGmWaxsSZPKSn4jn@ETaTylMPbZGlKSJU7E4AxuIh4vavF4Ml7FOfw10Z@0BV5GfCwOTDV@T90SQf4SK2JZwwhzlkjHLDMBdiCBXQk4scByZSF2IVxdXG2CZqzQTkcQH9kauSS5fl@IVRgDMfDEt/qjrDH2oRsoU5v1l/x5gvu8Aa5AZj5BEqWNTYaJ2hj7FE@Ub7E4IKY7o4amZZsNrQgDGTDHICro5FVctojhhnK5DhR2LwC/zVQdD2N9wmYzPRWeR7vHWD@1LlCZY9eXJrdr2/3D7WDb1vYOzsyegLgtVuNi7CIei1/BnxC7TyfANH4CjMUiZ8D41PzPxe/H4vE4zoEDod7GiEewnYtghquCX51K6BXOERrN5Nun5vCilJX4HAWwqKur2LpCNROcwfnklQaNImbZgQeoRTgXBINVPo/zyzHl1dj9XCtln@wfWA@dPYPxIzmlXEusx1hGlfBkS7Xi@@bF1tqpCm0iK2ZP0zF2P0bbwsVySRM17lGNsVMprlb4MZ7xUfll8WXp5ZPnB88P9oTYydrlmo1LCSzc5vbW@urXIGI8m4szdlKLTWu5qr/JrV6X1E0NDW0VWQXYfU8tSJnLOm/WdQooaBDy7hd@kJtuluBdy6jwrmn5lFavqxsaS8bG7778PbSZcrH76fZjFsf557/94x9pxb/9439NG8fiVzQnrWWLMYiJTrVQjF1cjC8uruDiYflYM8aRyhWT4OYLJGqsrqha1rKsKqsour5RTOW0@1ZV8eOqRTUZc6WYv9RTzMfcSz9Iy5QgKFiLIS@xgFUS2z0085p6f3MLirOVzWnVNWw3anhykIV/m4Zbjgmx0pNXl4zBS6fe7fdNjVyKwipvJbb5Vtpkb3Eh5K20xl7V6riQruJ5w2CdYANPYuFiWbyeUjbiDPQgVm9cVZspRisNoD2@NIwN6@Raqz9Zw/MHi14bFvwZGy79YaLAw4XX4M3Y@MIVExtJRel2fctcmwbL16FRbCiA2UawVMD/JOkk@e4Xfl3TCn/7x79y2bpsfaaB3lguF1Qt9rOfbU6siWt06z@DhLfYwgh0P1poQaMV6Ah1RsbNGZp@qtAhd0BdnVgoJPP4gQaJOiOKGGbfMrqkQQpnKBZRPba4ObZugqJt4FH5NAnZZP4oWRWEUBglIdrpd9IEg23g92WgYwsXwlcwCMZeVgOeK3xlDgo8RjDa2p2WO5w4YzqrkaB0ajPN7kESyOEraOlujY74@4xbAmanbNxMylF2iWokQrGR4bpoNw/GHOErkMS3BTqcsbGO1igwpmnBSCFjFMKTAroNyLsJeQ95ghb5Jqj0PEKacex4IgsEbeErIDsQFUwQKZi5CRGqwJW@AgSAMiR8wGaTbbJskl2YqVR1bpTvCreso9lAPTgJL2AyhNZFywtB4irGAy8Q8PHrc9gu/BoGaS7iGQDhMPiydw1UBExObyijkamK9wYFsMgsVIKKxu7dm2NVq5ndJKMSIfxTc4wzXVQP1nJcAVigXn3UrYhphuYOq4Fv2OyA4ilCF1qdxO0cViNJmYivV4IA/@/daLFFXqsqCqhiAfz64r2iAySDxEh2XocdtlljqlZMshD5DuDeIaToPHKoM55MP5K1z4LAK8DwZ7Hg2w7AoI6js4d@u71uCoHBmDlBw/poEIszA9@EATd5hYxu3wtSh6mgKOaQYvdMB/QZWo8PrO0lsmoSk82tExIetBFdy@EWbi2fxAelwtgMnjpajfPzWSNrNx0bKtQd2xaZmSMzOLjXHloE8CjfQhdHe2Kd44dY/LqhxFGMXLLOhS0fMSazefQFW0qLC@JtB5TegDZpZvRl1hl1mVZmCWpoZEnMCsElKREh3AbhGGncHhojQOnIMOj4lFtRlD7IVpM2mVN7YkK7GuyZMNpYruJ/LFg5N09N5RgNyUt2D09ZceMUMRTHsPvxtXffdNnQtk/Z0Dw1@KRwYsG0h8tAPQAJNw2Unf@AsBXc1KFl0ywDwWkeC35FeBS5s5SOpF1LzJI3n1l1LdHCGr2kwcd08EPAZ7oVoS9dl4KvEbszNzAORCZu4F0OWa7hmwWpxfHAf2jvRvDNHNXIwo6Miw3jBOingXkgdApjxzhjqNsKOMYA0@wEhjawF0Npv0IDAPU96FloNdBzKmgeBjBxuokOdD2fwVvsI5bVBIzIbTf5dpYABlZ9bRE6hEFSLIfrdaFiZJphR74CvXPUhTA0TOA3P0wftG50k0XHefNmaz44HHQorxrj3SJ4yUdesHdge6air0FgATBcgslaQkwB2JSYFDnoMP315Ly1C8RLKuwmpDRDCD6pAQqJCsGXwlnkiykCBDzQXW5W27cpeH5@LpOhy4ljyoaLXxFx8fPnyrhvgkBtK54xGvvfazTxO70@3LlL4h8PkseD8daUPkdfvjfjT0HouTV/a0wi3nPjODie4Ucy@iMyioXWqFxqUHsmfWCnk/B36vD2pzXTF0H7q2D7k0rxKwTCGIKZpmfpThqApdud03TvvFv1A86oQwJwqEUj8ETzs07wMnIDlznuhTFsD/loGNQentLKK0AS@QzuPGtewiDmLHj138fmFBJZxjnbdhx9lqDwJMbGBpyYkdjDZjDsUwg4YZhhF9wWqjltzJoLyadhchjUAn2JOWjxSri4HSg3jIvhUx4@hfApD5/OMw2ybUybXCRDryssDrZ6NJQYxEQwsyDOFTciOw8hyCB7M5WDwJizBb8r@HVqlDqgN3@DeqwFDQPaxBgIbiSUxsuTxknTco3zjWZK6UNjF4kQUOMAutEkmp53QzdSf3g2HNvugpeF9jFhVPLxRq/OwG8NvK1gGcMKoobB6WWiScP@yN@xwAUCv8AAAeUwCETRYNtLmMlqaIiZAqHhNMQ5jTliDR@ZJklffpDvB@ISJz0nbBRQMwII/cMiAZoQwoKew78ZFXCHF44NcYK4En3mZoSmteLNOFDyWlfhvKZKlRTBSpICNIHsKK7WrhclCIeqaFwLihTzyq//KPprH4x@D/rFcuypwfIBoypEuwruAwQRwu8uRFVWr0XqFTBQNvSh4cDItcvlU3@0hmw2lEDN4PlgEdxz/BB2IlL5nSSvHzprKFpiJWwKs1oNijir8W7J@0VAUk7wMJnrJ5sFDcFPzxkIwMgsTWb4yabRZNNajTMONl2R7DyC5JSQnPIkPPZ0BZJNPxloT/vB8ILV0wTpFDcqigBP5cMoiEFjkeHXsHH9@ws0@4dLpX6ec55DrcBvQyhiYzvrNJfm3oggHWFa1wBgQ7wBoMs/P1kRrjM8VQrfQh7FSRnwKP7mNwPOK6CBEQuuctO4ibCRkQ4MAr@YonEA@q6YagiiStPA@JfhPzEdeAY/9aZnZjGmuuiZSV/7@0fxbCJlIx00In2omRwyZNRknlu@TcmozBHDLzUPbJDq2uc2SywRtsFfmfhJlfbQbisjHfex4Efp/A@1j2fJQH/AJRR2f2x7umfnchWuNJnU7Jblz3UGs2/Z@C2LiHlskPW6tuFacQ8qtWP3LdM10gwtF54avtph@Pb6haic7DttVxD8CUyuxiJo3q5Q1G218DO5rVYCd/olK@GGZdr4h80zHhdQ/wVXJD2wJx/owThht78wOl7ybpho691Pdmx2ThMHYz8QJ1u3GfCwDsj/EDoACYa59lxzJDvSKEq3vQR90GFgj@w@SH0TVxYw9TXw@3PYiJA@HhMuaaajSluJWPynXpLopPWkn/STD07KPtESejJMry0CWCBGmjnXaYyUdZZk11qZHU8W5Hf04fgeRfE9uh1f0sKv48xV8xoP/LCss4k5BIg4RyN7NxpYdOBb3RvoLKASeqNcxRO8N4pd2ifWRUy3Ieq2H13uQftIh28uvIWIf7qK/rdXYJB8932rT8dvhx/NgN@McP9jgj4/5AZroQmIvp9E3nMzu7BpP3zPvCAufvltD0UIEGOJcVloAhc65hjUbjf8jEMA@I42j1uzbrR72q9V44FLcHLO0uxUW11FD1tdY6jPjG7Cj5mOwA1KfAgKG/Gr9ys4MjpiejbX9RIwdiXDUBjGkeg8UmVFk9HTZ8nk6mbFo5hh66GZcsJwfzX9MPwGa8YpvhqfrQY9IB6P4XTsmYnTn@PZeMatrA/5R2h8PsrHH16TaFDhboIAHfjoqabn2SZvY5@HibBI7zEihHHlxSKjEeQAIhoJulmHH0aiu0sKlRtJVAtqWVj8vsjyGjdvq/FIqwjaJF9ker8meVeje@82F2lqHNiche182BByAzJu3@h0ElGI3OfWGrOtGzwB/WiezloxqrSWMNQwJXE6zyR1m@SLpICa8T48ccLpU3giwL7htXiDCsqGc1r@59wYhYz0cURq8X1ASAcoESpykvtoRGIJgRuiX1yFeXZW5tm5kWdnIc@wByxmGYkkdBay9GsBq@e2KhgaPW8Fd8Yg1J3hcRvbhsuydQdnKy7iZrxipln8LF4Bhhw34pXdBDDleDdeeUgON145IsdpvPIJOOZ9K34ZrwTdAiM48EqO@@jvs3B878QrO4nkleDpp4Yb5CvHK2GdQpwt/koUAVJguUFqxCU2y/aL6TkGDGwkVKYZthg3jeoTzcOk6ZeBf/7FIPqWCAbiHOcGRWYppi4MGpERg@cDw0Zgq35JT674o/nuwR5tfwqjYDYp0PGiaQg8iOGx@CIz4ohhKK1owBMQRL5ZWY4Ri4xk74mOnzu0UKrkxfyJejLJA90EhTcgcnOeCX0myk8f1NciCF6B74cnJl6F5w10guwII1yTTS5BC4n6Kn5LobCuF3Hxaz9aQzTXvRgJsJWCKLyWCGyEp4MMR4tzmNnYHi82EgrF3fZmNA1NyvFOia33WjLiCn7PXBFM3n7JkDFEO3/ytuJE0iFqCywIAxuZJu9l4bhAvBiD5rwuIqnyzgcoRHgO9HCjc0qf4HroOykeZzdpGitWDUNBWp4lca5FNgmJZbRQNdE9nnuovO6i3aoPU1@DlFOca0kggEjKMBfOX@0PkN9tLr8HAnVAhGsZLBOslw@lN8XrW0fZa5gP59nerEAMTLOHyaXCUZjDnOSgHUQk89va2g0RH7d8cCGfZxpCvybtB2QLdYI76HZdt@CwUEpwzhY9TzXwPNVWE@qmRDI8kwOhRcacfDi84CGm86Ldjisv@LIqxhCa39aHH1zBzmIFRysP4VEBnGsk573cmVi0y2Xet4Ftcx9kqWqFcUZOy6VhNc89gd3T0m24bAseB63DhwdPH38dBt1isZj0x@jZHD/stTjXGo7jHDLtpQ7HgyVqi5bG7@TgYjdOx7sD2/HWTizxBi/hzBqEAR1yCZqf38eTPi@L8PNrfRfS8bgRivqwTufdQF/gSijq6Dhkmz5dPSCI4SU2dB9IIN4CvdOkrSXpizCtlqWPjFaLhq9WCzcvtVr@KIZVE6yIJ38WW1MmrkOfg@WfMzoXBDLFwB4esBePto/Z8aNdtvd85xP29YPn7MX202M8hf/s@YPH@zsMfrtPj3aZsLDJEj/9hgol0PWh0THwe55My2RyjCDv2OMZ5zuJnST3P9JH7JHdMXCZatPVR/cH/EW2DK/OU@2COjrDOUyTPvU3Mj3cb0HfpgM1FoWbLp0QxK3/DOK2Qacdoc47srtmz4S4Auq@Y9Nwg0NlbGhCDQK/Dc4bp7mQhJ@ho61D9HlJ3IF1Dsl1iI9rNwBG5/uvkMQYg3@37v8p7mm32tiR/E0/hbBJ6IZ22yaBEIxJDJjEs3xkMCSXA8Rp7Lbpe43t6zZgJ3DP7P7YF9j9v4@wrzLvML/2KWbrQ1KrbUPIZM6ZnBPc3ZJKpVKpJJWqSg1PSMLpfz9MwaPy4V5VYECHrYP97cpR5WC/KnYODuH1w0ll/x3Qs1I9OqxsHmMSZdw72K7sVLZK9IERyHkCIy38eh0NHkXBw@xElfpvePLt9aD79VtS640reHHrk69kJOavOyh9Qr8dfg0a8wXrOsLlC/pn0lGBsOdKh@8@wpwvgt/xhFMdBZP9Qeo4oqsR53JinWqDwbIB461gqdCJdibv0HnE1Ujg7ShBgSIw2PTsCgWcjHgaYSBSW2ijgrpvDtRAY1mBhopmATaCUgYrRUG3Gs3Pu@sEcgNqq7e7GFOTa2MjQvmCRd8qU5OCRRSTtjIIFN0bKh3UB@UL@gPwPXxYktUO@pxBvNAfOIN4yR9wKVpB2xGxLHNcDw6uUTyLFf7w61Vvh46FxSv9YdOnXeyqxIn7jbrUF/pWOAxb0aa7q1jLQ/dr@lE9DKlIRPnxXqd2mwdGwDcKgkzko0SybYOcKRA2TTxqkGZvfFEvpgI3oJ2Q3xxEwi46njhC46CgE/KtYa2232ETqNh0h3hPrGKEoOKGXD7o27bIYaTXJQbEm/6SeOhy23JVGDy1HJTcnKjRlzaSdOOlMkH7HgKbEwj8I2AAUOIGFb9OMxW5ryKYblOysh11gSNRb/uHmR/YuXFdDxIFpNWW/Wv49asjiewm9knKTpGwgy76GvRhWUlHmc1uH8Y4iVW6nwilYP2y2xuE3Id2sgV04kTTHOTGiQ1q@6KIK2tDOozX2Ol2jEovgIsfqPUCmPIptRLH89m5Fl/xxbXA@TAJs90douNfdG8C4@zMxUOk2wDVL7AQprNyVH6OBoQJrz@tWHb8IfC@y9XixvbmWeaPLy5eeslige@cVUaH@B8YE@uC4UHnfGSw2Md1lxxp6rKy6PoCS0sbPCktcZQrYLAPvAxhX/e2VtBpbG48@R1dasa/08e7uyKXyqBkkhcVR5d2LN1ccaqqdKnMuZAmIIbsBGRB1tvqi0swtbx@i2402AsFoEgH5Qju28euApMiRLXu4roJkkXeyCq7W8N3xAZZVMTXWaN7jNkf2c/2ZnFxw8nGBiXCIKetRLSrIOcdxzBLoflqAtz24@BAfj8d3Oqj2PH08EPQth@F9kO4ZRYfhsXTkgHr6WD/eAQsT27/EFhou/swYJ4kJ6FpTtfM6c6ltTXt4zV@meg7GnsABude1KBooEZt1x06olYhrG0u4Jhg4gVR9Wi7fHgoUrw/gbIg93DL0JBiEGHPig@xtW3YIWHn6UWTGXeaF0/qS8KiTf17bDBPJd4DokKuQVxJDy0s4rtlmuGQpZ6cWWgJQdb3JBAV5ZLYfVMyKDqVgO9hDwjIxp1mNNCa2sw0Tz5hZBqBS7q5vDY2bfjJwprnbrzntD8yAZk2QX4LPUum998nXh@vqXp4gYVBhLDBDVhJw3wD@4QqVNyDjJ6X7MFHukV1KRrZ8wI7rWiHhl@55Ar75xmKGIkX4bwWNsS6XBxL1Hh9PKeWOWSQiNOAj5aeMpEtmiFBiXj6sm52qBNPenZyCoJFJt58@dbkCih@fi@nMKKGnieLekFujrU5wuZUYXmO2lkJu/BwpmdoC70yLh7GqwJp@2hVmX9OVTxLJGpSNJ/aGJUIkFeWl198D/Z4K1TxzM/C5jlkXH4Ornqwv49BRqOI1PvAuZV9V6XHDPAI6di0Xg2YsYKw1JkypyTaTpORiR/gwnohQAYDuuNlouO1OmI4htt06DwjmdApy0QbjCGsG8qjZoL6949XhwL5u/XN/nh9PNgwE5oO3qNV/l63HwWxV54RysX4hM6vyW9Bv9@hbOzPdIVQbHJjetTZjrzt2OCVW4WJdN5mtqQpvZPY7NZVugaqhNSLHt4fjNq9wrh6L5MvmE3dqeyWxQIFemwmdJGpfsoxZM9s2HkMAZLBpJfA6YN8@J5Fa/AfcHAVSCATefPZRBvnu7gRRWDVfEoX@kizUClb8@O934zqfgcjgLipZ5FIuc@hIGlhywc7zjTNeq6QKA/IRb2ODaXcVMZLUVH4hgpdhJQEwb2J340JCz01lKUkute0umgfhQdbwZC1Z2Q56Wfzq7mV1xa1ruMO3KvT1@fuQr2YEjD5@p2r6Lp/2/it1b28aYq26P16MayPvv4uxPJL8QLqWnrO0XbzK8UsBTh9BX9Xxescca5E8A1FDsb7bD2@6FOIeRHvwwuzgq8KoU3zGnpIjHGpWLhSXIgudoPi1enKebFTzBWuTjvnBXTyGywWB4v5RRs/PIdZFGQMn8yfDs5xTjW1rkHnRmBQS7paUrqGCHINgS97fj/s7pb23yW0cbgAQBWYtPUmhTrfHTyD1mzoe@J1gltbqslcgRxr4QLJmiGvoDx6xpM@GdUxjRAwg15xYTUbDenvyLFmct51b9ClFBXeEFlL3IV31oxyY8qRRgGynIYqCCL6FwCcOI@NB0P8dcRW1Jk8L9fy6DvpGCBOsSSJw9RZKoU@hYio9OU6PbciL/Drl4gEXpZ9R8XE@jpdnQ2sFnmkxUNTDr9PDhO5c3zEAxD46dFpA1ZBK/eI3D4saD6@5/GBv5COakB@MmQgb9FKEVPQ/Ft8I/8mKr8OBGDCz/Cay5MqTrnygoUk@w6ScgFjnCU3/njMgG6V3Ckz2FiEzfUVY@BkKU40wmolmeD7zC2Sk2kF/2QLMnl6m2iGzu9wdiIJnVPLtwhpSV1KSRv4046L2UaxjCqmMhukmPkuNVDTBdujvQCG1UhsBe02IM20mInJgY/k3yvrX9T1R6dY57lGntMzE@mZRLrH6YxUnMuDCT7OtGZmSqW/xfnuRSrO5k7UVRS0ePGgp@seLEnivIXH8kbeoFsL48wbuiuZK3XCeiIhY6R8ntL7nDKbKKMZXKefcrrk7yXZ8xrLRN63yfrx15IdFJDxrLQ1GeNSrxO231jynmWZgmyWAmoKwcXpKkGhBlVR@mBKcQIrONTz07DdKMZQFvNK4tCYSW2sv015cpHxxh5Hg70YJwbWlDFiUInqXCTCDclhEeqh5FkDBMFERhNq5G6owiNZeGSAxVyzqlr2gpwY4NC08SFeRL/IO/yjBnsSOZUvPT1xhjEfcuPZuzlJIBK6s6npZEpKE3QX4Y@yUY/MInHdo3GI04XEvqEF1nUG7IPdRDX4rJYTpqBQkmKC7jpFUjrOkFfs@1AXYuK99ffsgvXOhzV2rx0MRQm3GT55YVkJB/dBEA0iDAVFEW2i616vjaeOtOC7JRdqGVVkaRmPW2KIxszuWRW07OH8Lj5Jh3Qo5IkDhHyLBiJxQnTdaqEzGXrAdm9RtKLGJRx4VqkzYoUGjJkXS@xmHggMvkECuB22TCS453j0IKWjnl8PPAvWaBGsfixuajOUV3CSPh39RjDYGExpa5b15@uw/tvWOzzPfZXPvcgbJLuRx8E578XL2MEKiKQSljBQ4HL@pWUZZ8N1PhvOIEBX7OJE/xF4M7gJOp3AKsGMQRkjWLRGQf8maHiWdRjoQ2CEi6yMJ5Poh9297tdZuQOLLh@YEb2EI5ePw4DD8BfnZz4urtNZmWvhoVV82gxdfRM2kIDK46TZxdNhOrDAMAFMDyx0FQyAKAuOSKJEZ88SF1q7XKEiCqiBcU6MswlNhk53ENahZ0iTZbUBFB@DxJV1GmOYQH31to/Owd40BNA9JqaAQkAdJT2GgyUPzX8IByEbps7YfdUzWZB@XRorMNyDfgjSNyYw9QoVM3CHDj56X6mK6sHO0afSYVnA84fDg4@V7fK22DyhM248KKcAvOL9wS5IF32azqfmB/AhVapCyRQlWKX9E1H@5cNhuVoVB4eisvdhtwLQAPxhaf@oUq66orK/tXu8TafvAEHsHxyJ3cpe5QiyHR24VKsqZsXlxMGO2Csfbr2H19JmZbdydEI17lSO9rEyPNUviQ@lw6PK1vFu6VB8OD78cFAtC2yYtV2pbu2WKnvlbQ/qhzpF@WN5/0hU35d2d8caevBpv3woyEjAaOVmGbAsbcIWFmuidm5XDstbR9ig@GkLiAcI7rqi@qG8VcGH8i9laE7p8MSVQKvlPx9DJkgU26W90jtonGV/hyrQL1vHh2UMloSUqB5vVo8qR8dHZfHu4GCbaF0tH36sbJWrBWHtHlSJYMfVsivwvkGqGmAAtSAdnjePqxWiW2X/COaM4w9o7@BAJ38CwgCWJSi6TQRGMwhsLRDp4PAEoSIdqANc8el9Gb4fIk2JWiWkAlpUbB2Z2aBCIOKR2UyxX363W3lX3t8qY/IBgvlUqZYd6LBKFTNU0CDjBFgHKj2mVmM/AV78CMxqKc51qTtFZUeUtj9WEHOZGzigWpHcQmTbei9p7mFIXkOJEnZRZ@BfmYqV5uSnmwBjUU5qZKbraHTEpK2D7TLMyDKyVSpOOIZZZ3UslJKZBjONToTXRMiaRnBx3aqFnWYXfUx1MVZ8XEUtF6/WcfBekjPrkZulpH6FCqTTtdrHUg02utVazXGfUjKBxvdKSDX4Y7kc2Ua83QB33qj4WVtjuq8nCLXxXB50kqEeHkBgTqb@czZ9868CR2SzjUAWQ@d9BKxURxEfm1ziUQqIRnJ2xAtV4ipJM0HvoWQHKmgr8F69hnpStIykTN0I/nTu4heeHIwPIJ1Z3ZXN4iaW0Ai/BqoaroRCItAfGZEgbFKVXhQEv7XsnFkd7vm9VrfbsB1HlaG8A9gHtmznO8UvgtZY8cx4eUKWjp3ljQGR2nfTEkafP0uSCdkvXp9aZuOf2oB@HIUNx3xArSlVRcpqqbS0n3NxtEhyhQxtge4V1Mm45tsr/VL5hLu53NLLwtj39/o7jy20F8SYtTDhnVK5c/p5f84ZYIBRLA4gSSgjZGSzRhllb6Iz30LGS8x0GzbQ8gfm6suA5nUgCSxkr/22WSfOxv1waGIPcvjdYWlv83hnB0QnYvtydfnVSsHSYbd@cfn3BOuhwLIUdawH8zis0yjJGCVbsPChkWIE9I7Znxg4m8WMGLhddRp9xDgP2m4jacmEggybG@HtQh000UsFSIeUoAAcs5bi16kjUzKAnWiqg6258oe0xPdhrUQ8II1Z2iPqtSH@Qdh6@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@LujnMxQWXI0IAoGEZ6c0E2m1QPnjvo4Xfb7f@Gcz8ugTqNoKEjkxogSRfInVTpUIzH@oCb3utGpNGArkANiKZEnhVp2lAV5uhXkp2kXVMqjo6JsUupJT9ej2ZSZS0FFcWMK2sH5lvJQGcilZZkaFAdLDS/tEyoTNtw3T@4GaNooclja5E662iRssaLiOIztXTEJ5ab@ukEn6SSv/gswtEDX/CMWy5BEWFcs@K56qScI/zQpuBTGPQbpk4UVjINv4fqN9r6dDvEi0p1KMP@1f1BFIxgB1DPhsMswajZf@pedmpb3bbfCruhD/s0jPo@ZImHjyN6xA5r9bu3Ed0dRAkNI1NjFD9zfBkOw4bv@lyyYITmigZBzzbNFAb9UemSw0SQ5hyNAOMrP4m/e@Mx0nSZl8txISvpf0r2eHmn8GDZF/lphflEHwFIAbcxZkHBPqQDckwynE8LExkuHstg4HghMsJ3HrDYS2D8GkhExzAJjBUyE2YJZiNwZ/YgxqeNodugGIR9DLQUbAd4801k02fXx1uUQYq8QUuBNZFfzRlF@RRliHEI8WH0MLmXXv2LsQcEfgL9/Itp3DKNEUjENVW0pYj3KzLKKOBC5oEhyWiSxCDFwlbYMdwP6c6J4TjUZPLoIWqQ5Q8simSYvQmuxBFpw8YHr7izayByaiMHJ5V5Me9Q3A5cgpQGdu5hhg2@Zz9Lgx8PcVlzhoJpS0K2DaQfIlUdqIT31I6Z15ooc0zl74@YpaWn9toYAYvTTM6M@5LtlFq5kAdKyPMrHmt1@yCMU2PUk6Ye89Gg25t/IvUelB1TI7NNo3Xdcb5rCMzMVoTJcqFBpC2O8HFUsMbxGWOaJMXI0gx4CLev9KzZfJyIw2INx1uxNvoOHR6iWWw3pScV3d8NHvs4Kd6gRa@aaPSQItwxSGlBfz@tQcNrD0sQCZO3VzWSGDUUGbURPxqgxsikqfR0ChH3SdzH6NEAymG9DaCd2T8PEnXcSE6FPFVJiSCXSE8M3I5OmyCXek00vsAwcbzC1UJKLziH7oiO8vKZCwwyjAkMEFfFQSbWQ7EGN@6sMT6i2wGadg2thfIoieBpw7Rw0EH/NcEoKr9U7kiLh9ookz8vMKShhgS7Csr1GCTlbw6vp7UhQZkgBQzxKaTQLZqQTZdPb9XPtgXyAQQuTcnS0jfnYmMcsQjYwB8zqTbENXBclSyZGFHJgVAj0QBjAXYprXbA21Vc/YV95ni0bpDDCDYQ/NnGn0VZAsN5r@Q0tbHIsDHCLI4kN482R2Q2uEjMUPyO5JdDkZe6tHEFAAFjDOWLeYCAYU0JezwUoNA7JuclEJV9BAWLeRyW8JGiosZ2nlPSkagyw8tlI0duWo7XJozMVCCwsJieJ0YE1izTs8RQYKKbiouR49X09sQ5YEGseJ8pDl0heyVJQ91zTEC6vTnnxBLlNC/cnORgSny57CQSNX9T6uuckZobTwX6aAxPM/nx1NVcIjVR7dJSsmiiJNDDMWtNJAIpHBNhLRV@7h@5ppghz7VNqLHJSKwypH023q4Nu0zYt3m/RmKdnLLVGkPBMz3D1farxlesJIKyPx6AXczTkQHGbv/p1irLVIWJvCuA4tIpZxebN4S0Yk3hVI/Nwp2uirSnAxSoPW23KT4e7ewkwr5ejJSh0VXQX87lcsjEF2bwe2VbjaqksJtN5s42r9vtbO/2T/2PF1mS/UFAVwKsqR10AF0CgyLyuv0W3wyBOEBWzJ2Rjqy4179uNs0rGPCEEjsPuo1zymgIgiagUBu9fDwiBRCBlBPsF2wgtu@L0KPv1ueFpoSijqGgNJoE36TU6RmQBz800T5bn1QRMBTMypoJ5i2nuPENZxC82YQ6i8IXO99i8@TU@6Dd7rriE94@jJECZu7HC@zsmAVynAVPGMm79zqieLSuCG7CtuFXjFlMXkdwamJS90youPAYG/8waJWHPTt1@jkF0wo0eRGbuYjxqV2RaqUcGSz@CWCZDwHtJ@W@8nt2neg0nhmmejmC4yfA6EXenbr3SWRxSCcmafb93EjU6eh6FKwBmu7QWkDFsqfupZY8kF0TN3U2zDeRhjmGIXHCmCtPK4GuZv86sXgzaDafJhXpGgDu2B@SiHwTys8JRDoDoBEohx/QE6No/1sGhvXOWEARXuDgZR2TcgcL1LCAZT2rF3@/tUulkpjrLS6KUmkTHjIZUdosiW38sLkptuF9E9@fF5eWlwssc7edb/BxU328F5sAgzSci/XL/ja8QloR/cbQWhu7eC5bnHMLc7Xi@kYhyp6WNtGtH57@9u//@bf/@K9sSb78D75s0svpZ53J87zsXP3b3PP7Ar6fbp/Pz12czvXO51sF5LK/U9TwbmWQ8WPzUa9/YaV5FjC@kh2p2mdT9BlZVKgrAa/8/m8gXdZEuh5l0/JrxDdHkYxN1wPje4B@lBewhVeXDoxv5QGJNAAdoToeeqceoAEezDdAScAF7UC5PJ@tKMU9hoPRGfSpSlpG4qE1602APi1xJAX0xYUZKxN2oqCDGvAbWvNy8yzLh99wUJP8m/28F7U2u0OxcGaLhZxYcMVCKkU/@ZXX8NWZy4boncvZYDuQSrmQEh8toJmhiEJa6NH@ge7aGSO3Zc3RlT0ISYWpoMzsBefq3R85y/CFa1HLmsGbNwWrSOiQCYukv8117qFbvkGO@1TC1YYWCjW5i6HKjBMV3b@4BPIjNgSIa75igqx1oUo86SOPZHzKqi@yry26TYgAI1kP3@3QuMcPMBfNdaTNc2Ivhdcckfk8f8W5scDO0IQ2pnD9MQJ0oMLbyRx5Es6n5y228jZaSc1kL2yzfZL52NZhFAyUbToX@kMYTMDW3Cbh5jrSr0UacvPxikiF@njFqCo1bvstLKPI1XV7EPakuwLVjgPqm67tnkcS9igBYjgcs39tcoSRokBFihrrFr4sayQaXWw6j4SOdE2HDnY8PjkyiJD9bMPYvhsb206WvEQUOzAPEFLalK/ph@1IRl3pE7Fbfv8Cbwf0m3Sh2oDPzUifh5etjmHcbWqkPYJMJufxeIampHt9v3XluyK93z3q@6MKTFuw8hnUPQdaiCGYEAkcfLLqac1TCHOLZJcQRXRTyHIILy9oj@T1aNy3Ke1zgl2qhoIMu4KDIMFORMngLtFXY3SMufoHOsFEeUJ469NIKWJJ8qKlkYSUMt1maJhNDB1L1WCOHT1wUhajqkem4gVZ6Bon2is6@AVJ3sYYAbLulPQClK4IK6@xfpydWkHHT0xOvbalHP2zBcHzIo5nuoqSrZEsdU1qPr7xDrGCdeTnZBQInptUOCNrxrZnziJ5nVvanEcoyLe2xc/6ItQX0NEFZuQZIo47IQvLsRkqvgPDExWy/AcIzbbfAvxGt/4IWfEsbb@ZzTqnn8865wv2Wefu7KtDmEiRrGbZjEjLw2wlseRYgZkx6yZelVVapEINnnWSGc46gn1YDBIAIln79HP2/C4LCJ2l8Qr6szQTJNFliEn28fqyCD47gWY6iUU2bc04C47qfPtN3hEwt9Iv9iF/cPgXsFCbSlLTwz6n3wRQ5Kf7@zW7nETZ1aXcy6X8S9gJtYJhph9c43ybia4vgiEsJSLczsLUc/Y1wQ0JQtwPI78AH4fQTr7WhH1PIumkJEWoHOZUj6XZCsp4zBOQH6hM4VLRxcXReXw8fMQNvyuA5VReigXFpoMG99k4f0bdK6zHj1CujXuHMEeilQHbiJAKNYOQ1eUrD3Goo4bLPPk5eWILY7cSEOjebNqYLTrdTkYu1hxvvoCLaPSaaa/mVnPjY3RiiCZG6JxcTM3PivzGm1d//e@D39OD9MZS9lMffgfp39Mrq2l@hAd4e6HebtIb6XXMtnKfHmVhDwyPr/76v1B@408AB1NG6/BnY1nBWhmlNzJFKnKX3liBh/zSEtT7f3/5C7RhjndseBfrXM0VhFhBUWTL7xDvQrqoYCt5WzofixVyzEIYbGEIe3N4QcOo4dJqjtR0aWlVcRPIyFfKHkVO8WSYNSBTIdZkKHsKWBlxgSJWkGGQyoSiKQzbDWW2gcwboym@PPNWItgBfJHmHLpKbbrxLEKToTneFkEH2lwj7Of5YSP3JqXNO9ZSyqakoJaQuLWTsnb1ReH/AQ)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ap7o9)

<>^v code is next to the last `@`:

```
@<? ? ?342;!
```

`@<` is also for Gammaplex/Klein 000. In <>^v 1 `<` is noop if IP moves horizontally.
`? ? ?` removes numbers 3,4,2 from the stack in Klein 000.
`?` swaps top two stack items in <>^v 1. It doesn't fail on empty stack because it's implemented with [slices](https://github.com/Astroide/---v/blob/d28c13e3/udlr.py#L211).

Comment: It seems as though you're the only one still working on this challenge...

Answer (score 3):

## 344. HTML+JavaScript ([Sciter.JS](https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-js-sdk)), 15565 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{

















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8;[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#giogrl61k54op>a>std[]!![ ]?42ore>805在ｕ92g=1\'\0C0ML
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40XHh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt1S36pStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKJMACQIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3i2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HbGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr7uBnP4vhxZ7aw1l/aHvMM1yPdR3z1HBkdm/G7uqmm9eygoCxtp3@ZGRYnlsRYkxlbKhb/YneN1jPHHqGk2auYbC2MbTPIFxjbHNiTVyjW4e3LGOWccb2rI7ZBQjMs08My3xjOBCWY@y@MbwYXXisY49GutV12dgxLY9C84w91eGlN@mcML3teo7e8UzbgqACY8@soT5qd3VG0ceOwRMVGYDqnFCaxZASY49txzUgB7tjuK6NnmXw1B3TfrT95JMr8dUM@0QHpMZDY3ole1Vlz03D6V5NobHPjh48uOqbZZ9KtsUeXEdJzbHtiWfveVfh59l237B0psllWbsaWABiesawlCllFoIg7IHpQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQ4pnTUZtwwkiup7ueKbVZ2emN2DewHTDdBTbHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU1IZPd8KADa6rITY3ZmO1C1PkzbGs4godExeyYmCfAAgHglvIHB4Yz0GVSm5UEjYDpzAY2hEUBLCjGIf99oT/rMnnjjiccAt67p6u0hAG3PWNfo6ZOhl2ZtCANikv/ZwLD8RgvgZABxZHOsXk0INWPetvVul2WgvQIeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPbAeoBrECjHxg1H55GY0p1A1Uec@usHwmA@G7oQ9iqw9d20dmETUMtKBPUp0h3KeO3Xf0EVCjaxBNP9t7ytyO7cAb/DAu7zc3genoHtvcZPHdJ/fjrB5Wi@y0hbCKauwcqiAWBLJTfTiBFhKtCRvqxwlTC1hl8bV4hcWBLFqG5XIsB92zxLQ8EEnNlMEB/VzLqvArMK3Ecir0lHw8jfn0HL1vDg0OpY9QitjAtTzT4J7Jsaxa4jH79rDHo3UosyLLllihyIp5VoR7mZU1yA1B55hazsOvAD@AVgZUVPhlcxzQvN1DO8W2tsN6@sgcznzoBL7D8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW4hWF7Q2A2gP9FMBLQ/MEuY4RMh6sQgUeysaGQpwPWSvP3h1g9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaSeOFcAfGcOgnGbiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdPcEMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPH44HetvwzA5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZ7CnCpQCdlg/FUZYHnOE5dndkYMikgUHZxH7n7TBhBSwmCRxxkVsC@xpCe4QhoqMjK8OObRBjCuCYnswgExg3DfsUx3niLgvZuMSB2g4O6zBcdA3HYRgXZAE3TbzKnbRd4/UEB6Q5Xj1gfgbwyJ5uDkMEqEPqHnFSeMZdyG@2iHbPsUfUa0fIi4a2PV7B94HznSGgh/aZMUd9zhj18XgIww/4G3z0A2TOdBJQSJqJ5soRgkSYrjMwASBlBWzbdIwO0d4vOqTOAoNfRLHCtPqdLEK5FxmXsmxsA892MY01GQ4rMGAYHZatK13jVEEfPnYtjlmIQzCawZjkg2jrIFwg5oRFCOmOJtM4eRTUrGuPFovGGdVeWPSBiSPM8EyfQe31gEcZU30EIhBDOcOCUXEELYbXINYECHlYrD3Wta24F0I5c0AagEKHJSGJA2nimSMDxEUbkmCN5whpZJOEWXsGTZmolZNJPuSYXCGULFwlFPfIRTx4Z4FxszvpINUwb9OiFgTjjYvCkmPoXe4neA47Ptbh58DAOPZFYhkdGPEQUYtIbjCqGkB9X4TpEEQc7A3LBTnMlZmJAiu0/L7dg8Z2ZkLZQUSCpHPYHSICkiD0msodWSCSYwManQyZyTrjMQN/EDygeT7IlGAst1@Z7A0EDgcgi3UmjjNj0zHUhDmCWF7H7vWg9b4xxgMAwUZd1pl1oHtCJWPrEbo2caLOeLGY87d1A@JYKN3tPP0a6xtAdhj5eyjOY5OfF2A8piIQKXSLSwWWDpTCInTGMyILgAlT9GxbRv@ubbjUWGznJOz6mJlr9KlrQD/rzZnRCKUcaKUWSWdd4Dx@90L4mKGwtDCYld8KPjEs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE63WQ@0kogsgAKb3ukYY89vJzaxM9OKCE77D1BwIl/JBya7A2H9Ltu80mogathyIkIBCpKI@tiX53Tktb7qA2KCZcxld85ZhrNr2UOM0yu5iy8xzgIGL8UVOIypS6AUSUxi4iErQe5odgbICz3kNiS4QG9zJteLD37R7J0Rk3ph3oiNCmxHkJXQC/FYDUOC3/A6IHk8RFj1BQ@MuuBxC2jdHS2BbIdIDrtRX1nRZWCKtwEd2Za9BCoQM4SLURZDqC6oMR4i19CHYWOk7uIu1BEy7Lk2jgMZjKHjse1Az@BMZ0YqGVVZpHX5mkwiHCuSoMkvDq0wZMRxwPdwFIQE4yHob9TFsKeCiKoDpwAmxjUN4Hk2zzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEsty0ApV3dmHAgUD4ZnyGjGTMcBNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6FzIWZEc1O@vZi5ji96ZtM3pVXWmg57yK1c41R3WQ03GAaEDOlEi3nPjySr5U8pIkKjYY0@hpPwuQkSKJEOVJ3qgHMEg8QAYzeHM6iTEhS4mppk48XolMQkOTMhlNPYVfexdxe4V@GGjGZ1Av6a3KuvD8C1JcJfQjzDBAEXGAN0BOQM6IYjs5XK3rbML4B6glk93KDUKl/RU5VyYl2F1w7x8QiAu0fLKPAvX6ZBDioxqWAKMTiWnQWKBgO9JCUoogoei@GMrepC0x8NIruGeE4smLliCiyJJdh4K@TAAJAgZE4QPs2N6LV9cuXMnEFzWajVobCBNAdvsJqPqQTDDIwOnhsgySSN@JrJnH3rYNxJJKC9GvuTYgNgELbVWZ@fewIEeR@@XAkQCsgoWtuSAsH49PzFPJt2rFW2hJ0YSsdeB0GR2PLEqwODPe0PtJqrGF6gKKkQcqYqNF9MT6GuNl3yxQkU/mmO4KP7WfFQiNZxADPy2upREPKnvN2/QO7PO0BcJuAs6O@dGbUD/xJ8RCBlR2pcJgk57radyINgdOBz2dPvoYc3vizxQaZtWZcFjaHf0IXmvY3QxSPto797B9sHXWktgDM125aqHYuZKBRxqJ1Opb02UnKxV1qMw5oDvt26GjQkX44iCH8wkexoRlWYdGFymATn3Dz69ShKQhJAclAO48XdFpOFxQOgS2ro7uDIIs34qBVmGSYK4TNpjAczQgahjuB7g83Ty5g1W3lWkxr4/Yjac6BxA4KnsWUE6GQOvCGBBULvHR0RKC1KoaeHM7NwVjRng8wlKzVeRIVE60mQ@2X@we1AjsP4khURRFNcDWUp3ujK0@eGkawjL4gD7A1eHpeQ54ihPE65LCdzpLBB4XrdsBXwAgLqObDNpOAqK5g4A952rZSNfqRO2AHonCFflyqg81PlQRCN44BDXQZV32ShKAfPBKvRaOmKFoYvDViefN4q5cnTY6szz7EaB0uwqjAOB3OhA0IkroY88lyJ9sdpH//DRNcRdEiJBFZACzNwhkykvdyig9iKZLO4qO6Ch2UNDfk4cT2RiUlHiwQSr3HFJ@YzE352aXiKT5E81CXEh9@3tPe1@ENmf@6OZDFIaUBfHkcnp4YJIx4U2YtlDu2@zDUjDpcMgQxCbVhZzu29b12pIR08sagzXVID/4sSNPoaxxnxDiiOliqqrfHVGt9wz4NJqIYtEIgoRKIXiy6/0Ux3INS/34d4XuzCIqPlMJnRn6AISRNIQudDVifiSB5MgI9nHZ2kBw/WVa709CJAiCxxYaJ/RhQm358FLPYljysrS@EtR@op9jeKv7NmVpgU@vGmBI0KyvSdPH@092X28/fmxp@XzC@@5TLkAhIP82iALyQNON@ytG7xrYrEQXAz6hoPdC7jABBSUYNp94jrAuGWMInMEVrQavjKV@Io9sOJu8mphzjBUemV1eBN6jJ2PR/UTgqLdHaIy4vDlPRzPsf0MPG/sVhQFevlg0pZBaVVedeyh3lcoHQwMw6Giouqyt4/zGu6yFICMOzN4Cj65BaLDjGYQ9eHIBuWFFgmRNbAEB0@zVkOzPwBdGFcSDScphy2YSqN0QUMAXVkJy0YMmN6Atv4zqCeRN@2PVK3E27Wa0XKKGERb6P4Qd61ngOqUgNEKSJG88sqO7xzfYTPg0gjpKpAYkzdoksNlOBYMGQiSNGuKen5AHOIWOF@KvIJo9HqCs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpXmcgebYE8CS7R/MGkVbYczu61ZM3fEeALMh9H0NRs40Xx8dWEwT04zuEGy7gNWbNhtpMVtn1JBt@/GQVWu9C8bDtBh7QdskJTZOebAU/6@rX2VlXp97VZYo3GvtjjjRmj7dBkHpjA7/uGtG@hwmUaKCysRBXwchvlSUTQkNMKuANKaVAh4KRFpqegnhJIPSieAgtB/hWJAGbz2bwcvAF8QgfQaUb271px12a8Ue5BmdL3TEQkSabO8ilXZwf9GB0DFs@cmmoXGTS7MyI4zy67vLZSkjkL5YG6UFXCyHQrHw4I22Fy8DQCCgVqefAOaBd4bTpYD7LiEo/tDTIkHDCyQeQICxaPegDn4HEvCDbvCA8J/JZLNKJZZ9ZCK1tsJLUNj0@2W9PHFw0NLvRskH0rMbjADQqXISv0@pi2@jwWVaemEoBSqDORsbIxqkEkK6IFRhUBJ2vTKIu6OKMNXSrjITLLwBfYnd3gIt1DD5fJI1QiYImtcvinqNsS18ouvQGWvMNshUWfju6tE6VfhQQYHGdmGZJ/BlQkk7sEUV6TvMtGHgvEHeF8cwbQImhhYl6zR4b1lWdj2uEiWSV1nPjcWD4ppU4j6@trcUr8Xo8Da4tcG2iawtdKXBtkUsiF8aT0UUp0uTC0AalQL9m/LIRQJ4mm9gGpig5vDHHCb1RqWSbab2h@k8Nn0moCqA8xJbwAXDiyVoNncmkWD/DNRuQ3yNl38G2c9hxzLFPgq@AQMDffRpkiQig3qM07xhV1E1vpsio5oDSaKCImXDix43McfP4/LibOr6MpzF1sqrXQD8E5uUlRnLfsSdjENwauYoEvC3ZyFaa1XYtnolvJBIlaQgZ6cnkx6VkSue0TsQNaFOJ4@M4kNSnTqMzcAjeNK0lkyGhAI@eCVrGcJiIy@clyL@dbCZTcUibjKeBLdficaBLB4ngUqFxRoA3ogfmFEgJHROGuOiaAjFIWpzC7vqFMR7MnGiEcNYNpGycQZ8v@uPeCOTiUS75hqePCnQLmn4g9/J4INzi5B3KS@MZ5@4Cx/RYWdiyEoy7p1JvZHu68pkMSpMcGS7ja3FFkmAkpBAOiYr92HSxC@uWYU/c6Ezj0glQzB18jwYTYJbBfp40tCpzLBidgc3i63cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQC6HRl@yERRKsHFEpAuaGeGCXyR9rTQrIxKSHDWE8zN5wvj13KYW5XSsAxmZPYt2zEkIAmkEGgbCm1iEurM3wmzRzNf19Yl/FAa0lDxNg3giA@Gtk605ew6sh40HkXSg34OSQ6MrjAE/tED9ijzunCMrrIh0Cqt7QxghIDSICfWwtoa@QGK7Y67sjeFpEICB9xoINfuQOg8Y11N0wqdfK8ShGGrAGIPoJJQK7VAxQ2CJBUCk34l7/JpoUBHf7J/f5fPndBgi8MrzqO1RnZ3AnKlrzcdGFY/zXahPZmWPTKBDEH6NyfDA9v2uJYPL6tmZrjSbI4mQ53mfK5Oy9yYrmO37SFNBd2UdB5/4rj6UOeTUEHo9mePQdZ/dnRYkyuRSIp@Oroxb5yHXJ4tp@dedM2R1luD5SGXN0xxPS/iuBVsk0M24wcUMGDib5KDOgr8i@gfdClcQ/H9S@g/wg1yICv7swj0Gnr6EcsUETfN4c4h3/NczVyi/0odLIynUjwuOM6xPVc18j/1er0F7yx5n0jImoZz7xx5881zCzpiFKU8j4Q76RbiRAEVKE64oe5qPJ95hXsNBsYwWEE8AMEEV8lgbB@i@AS6CUrifM@bAYL0GBdDiEPjEhvrgKzpXpu2gD41lnhsIbZG/QTGMAUlF2FdYf4Ud5V6imX7S5Mu5542qPY0e7JZ54vZqDo5XGtT@OT7egtAbNarwQalVdEwp3g8jEZQCTdIQcWk9ftrRQ13Y7g0py5QkqrgKqA1TLWMdDwt7jYv4opLZOgx8fh4@nFG@xzUD9xdtn5H6RtVzHAVvapBSNwXVdszJoFgh7H4/HRnAOyEpaaLpIT6mVg9e9iV@GIYtAvG1SisIH8vQrjrzd/caJhOsOGNdhzypMhGI3vlrsG9UqX16xEiu@tCQNBLztnFSfr0gjVgZDuV3fHQ9JrsUvbs1gBJ4k0c6@o@PC5qOo4@cwV/K0uNbR988lkj0@QQhJGOC1wlXovTYDsnyMcgD@H@WnDhhhzP9GjApw0HJpZXlQGpKa2FAPoAg2dQZWFGfokQ9QvjYl6WngEKacJAzN3ZKM2M5KXcG@qeZ1i8zfFVxtXk5stBfjY1yn7LX1uosAwtwIAAamIYoFhlh0f3dw8OZGi5biK@iws1FeiOemcAcsiqQgeUjBa@wj7uxtnHmCaJ2rkAXQ2UjJafHhp1FRo9qBmQO7KIvuEkwDOJaywd8KZlLUrIBTGfQLitquMRjUJgCSMJZSJglaX4P7O4RuXjWYEWnyJKArkTdypAWzMpTyzztezCeELiKUSJc50UhoXaeoKY2rqapNbjmCNcIQZFimRDKEGjwaQ3wPQgssiazSpf6oe4qGc5faSuKFJV0K7fmhpUfQ28QXIhCH7y2lv2opGRys3U@jJQtIfM37DLyx@BixAWQbvG0mzXE9Tfr3VkjgNf8uOM/BlpzVd2pVfYOneIfGqZogf7oojp0Daqxe1Qi5utoJMhK6EZFyxIwBJi/nZqv81SOHF@UG0wGXkkkuw8JLqGJGcXF0RDtq4xoiG4VMYr4zJQMoExPbKhNI/8rdRRIYB6q79fBPvssSAG2tTigiyGcEldOb0ihEqnYjQdFwJN68SmZZ3Q1crIah4FvzD16GR4PWXPdAd0W4ga4sDjaquwc0ftHt2WRKDVDX/dnDxo3twXeUFW1JUDetAU@pKcF/eKLGTbNnoTq0@LjOhm0utbYkrlEkXutdvmqqhABNz@FTyXRAMmhe1Zk3OyGuzNxhkXGI@AcXElZV70q9uM2ALdYXTwIJX//K9f7wL9r9fOAAYKnGAMHS0YurGmpN7KyvKT4gvdllcsnwefDE2dCEOu20B2dAeKpA9Dx3LQtNYuSTD8j3DlwK9xaJt4A@HwhmbGMecLf8FzeSbL1s4sYJmdVXGvbLviWdEqD@hvXSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYEz5SktEk0Y2djtSwd4oRo2Z1/tg4k34HeTTWyvRHOPvpr7px8zk9bZqgIaot03jhip39JNJ15bGJ/1QTi0siTsvPS31SiAO@Ku@LXQuLz4voGP2YZwNnquizYc25Ywet7UK15q4Y6lNynaXv1FHGN2QgzPk91VRTP9QU@hYTTVzSLf3bIk@dGgo/qYHBbeUShGimVfIPNTbM5RBBh/eysINBMBxap1UKpNdsYI8Hq9OjwojpS@Xl6eeyh1Oj2VTAQrftirxyTIqsL@R9ZZaheHKHOlDSetGnCuZ@bL9B9eihkuXlMY4xYWb06U1N6c@DkidyVB35q4bmvgcj2C1YNXEsz9sPDU7NogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gBN88Idw3TLbLLwVxGxi6ohTiIS6FrOQuwOx7uDF3Rpt6DofEdmbjvNdJIZHsVpTr2Gf5Wig8DUE35ffmI9mYpVu/BnKRhZ6jDOL5yOFiYA8Q5xlsa6pnpGnRbTtiTpYh6neFS/8UuEMzuRWfrbmvWrjm0XXZI95sI1HeACvy@vEFHaWnqlkRz3lH3DTwo2Mowr1B92LeHhVJf0eG2stYnTg/5vv98Xw4XcihVvYVDBeKPban@cyVfP1Gck9sqiA54ObiNNeK8YYhdxqb8JZbVpQPFANfnlpfsQaZEKWWFz@ityBhXVs70WfD8OYaOVaQNho7xjMRpkO4wQbkEDs/hIvbPk1vu5ty678eUroEt3laISOWeDA0YrOh@rUqZllE/MIWaybw/i@oNJ8bEWKpo7LdfGXjc@AYl4/2RyvjFWPcn5HENAE@ghLHe@Jrhe2GN4zS@3chM9KHZMW4XZRaZ2hik7zGqzk/B8RQd11P0rcl4oVYXtDPr4GaSDcZBl7a7C9hhyIfyodItktKCfO4a9LtRY@IaHu4Dq@UymYwvwEQWVhZebtKksmHaVya/L2RMPvOc53FxMc2JOJfnQWSJ7jRcyYK0VYo9RS6XFcu0DG@G9/fkpm3bHn5ITQFT7ZooioFkSTtqb6qxa@KOf1aEzacuXJzwaPdWTVrw0cbXLYE@qDTfVOnRlZ/3qk0J1zZHuO60@Hrz9E1kHem2XPCcNs4J8T22w9WypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqt02hjp/TAu5m@CV5eyN8BaZhr8mi2u4fOV2vuIeu8KUxjMgltkFLWVgjAx6vUHK17toUsB/rIw0tfG3KnhqGB1lumt0VkUYm8AXLLwvLBVHhCXPtkC/8nA7H@opQ9ww6vuu4sDB4t5SIu@N9L7BbVncxCnnExa4aYardXPn8qmLCt8o04Fkc@MFq5sEdKoTY@YGz6UAH886UK@T0e3TbVc6fwfnQN@jt6/aqXp9iLUG9sAaGAO@PTx8W9U5oD163PbITagD1v0B7lgbjxd2skfpObSHw/ehJ7JGzihtu7cUp10844oHtD4I7kxvQ4D/uHXyTvc470DHyl4zMCYwLrm2Z48Nid5WRR3iRA@/r@KhwVr0zzuDdKOeDxQJnj8v/Ft1y75ue@MxPVrj4cSlGyWV6GjybXJTj@9Aob2PttOX39ijtux7yv72FFoCX85i2qbXGeDZcN6yjb7d7gzM25BuG7pnmSdKMOXDX99Ld0XKmEy6j97y0ATyOjMZ20stGn6Ij71Vle7PHvFhLXTcIK8sm6Gj09fSWD/puHw2FF2sghPCkd7Iz2hX6JR75fXE9OZAI1uWwuldviyBjlW4@5skVkpWdBRizob9zRMrWykJ6SiQS0YGBB51VbaL29kiXSyb5bdVCEVLSRhFtp98CLn9LT40O2hG5m3Bf6F9LexNWjrIWYNJ373OMPl0fRdENLytnragLcuRKWsYs3TLf6wiszZU8CwjPFsgc02MG9dU8jcuqlA8dSjptgmPFjyg6iYr59CG5tjldyb1Vi7F@VuWQBe/ul7IaTNbrkz7FdM1enwJBF23iYgj28ENxyCDSB1cSccZdGTmXPDijMuy@8DUpSGbRw7irhJblu4GWl794Zgpff7E6Ou4pfqR6eGezCWtgprssl1Et8L@6kR3za9OoGSrGhsaZuDLkE70BD@@LYH3WO@bnYcLFREi6RPY39DJHwvNH72u18XZwHRxR1PouGFiCpscb8TY6lqgNyyJeXXePrRJMe9A/LTj0tjL5tbt8QwPhc3IddO0uunRLKv/XKU6rtrrdSMSZ5PReOL6j@U40J6p6Cz06IT83TMTgEuvgbWygT70ls9UR6ZcQQrzB8W5c5U0/oU5tPvsi1KGgdAGQhgK50sazj0Ynp/ihhzHWtISKe/3XPbEiQ7J4QV7DXVrZJlkWqZ382yO5@HmnOCJheEjBx5EUB7hXb77oRCko@UUeXS7rD8/gXzL@A4t79CeOB0DnaFZkaha4Odq7ASbjPHgho1mUc6iWlrHHkL3AsdwaZfp2NbEk5yJdeOoULhxVKiwaakQaQYs8dXdx8@S0dZAm7Jvk0INUP4m7nA2d63cMHClkZkWCGKr@ehi7ECXuM/NIR3QjuBb0myjzaYOsev79jJ95@kMBpD3VpiA@U9G940OLhvemvcT@7Ft2TAajYFRjg4MfrR/YaPH8oSY7BEeXgf6dG/N5pDArhiEuLShj4021O9w7nqfsYgDvq97@oqhiOYGSf8LXbe2FXPYNpxXNOkXca9SaRcRemhMSbdY3WB4H5S8ToeLxDgft9BHFlZs3LFtW/xO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vf9CuYz77RfmBZbqZ4tF3T/lu0SMLrc9saqsjtG2h/x@w54ky@R7AnTHNFzlEZoyIL9Cjkkgfbk38pDijTxkrhqBJHuqu7RIv1zVmINUpx@wBWigOx0bV8J8xw27cyL2B25h0@EWfr5xoA2EnwLH0jsT37jibWgNR@0R3VYqDJHaPDDaePinTUY7PH16vTL5zJBvsSCyoys85x@wK@zUBZZ4CtpI8vZha0GPWqSqOaYbceqVy@W0WUeyTKPzRsdZM5voNZ@bXgiHMitPyLlirjrSjWgWWdHpQPvSnrS4dQ0EmqEheQMHdH7Fu2l6O7CmsmQ9ZDIycJF5cRVmpehquwMqrL18PT1kro4h@Sb9gJeE5v24fChtr5Q8ETz879/7igKDcKuQCyyMAOu6fQUfkJ84lv94nxb41Ha9njndB7zxFMAqdoLFykMSePCega6NVYWA2rMmQz770I/suxp1SR2TyGqtJA2JXXuGZFinEtl7m14vkc3PdinbaO3UM7qSb@4AVxqkR8ExrzCa/1yygBrljbjZU1U4YaeFnL/9cxlxzwLOAPKW7Uljl57K2H2692j/SB676tLxaXuApyOuyXEL9hO0UiYyJfVKdyLrnXw7Wtd0PeXeoSrtPNqTMcIKevMVDQkeuDK38Fg57@mbE9UVfaUWhKGGt1xAfHj0@FFqfhKTJXYGjj0yktHgncPDNJ40@crh0uBo6gfQO3r2dGXyvV1VTS5pvs8sWh1cxT2X5LQK0pEB2ig0xofc/MqtwlXHHhvdo9nY@AwGT@Tg7ntmX1hZyCf6qdnHXsjKKwlFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcq24YTPVfV5Yo6RW3boofDHyu0oKDlkFSe7XHq4acX/qhTDMv5OhA9LpGaut1bPlKBn9AfoUnT374uYqqqr6Hyo96BeWX5lZS1GWLY@PLRP32Mp2fCVFyn0kjxoVZJ56z7yojQC1q3gDafnfU9wtldug7kJQOhdWNrhzwxrplsSrWXdJF5UIDVuarsxyhfGeyxIhTt8TtHA89I1vnBLPUt0yJm8JeMjJ5JkZ@fe3m0JDnxa3hzrkyfP2FPdRVsjN0eMYmy8B8ZzyeiVhPNWaOhu5XJq1wFQ2o3w@uPl/bnCDnWna1uz6e2LcHTUFId2siEcwsI3imQMzam5bKzq8Hmtp8u3Gd2WNz/EYc8W5OCoDRof0Ltv/QtVzWTIwhA@1Qx/vaVmgg7OEujSZ2i2Lhp0tBeyhg7KLTJ4JJdqo4@MKW5H4bPBy5T6peNb4Yaxr5hcPZzcFFa6ISx3Q37XwtCTZeWMegPA/A1hLC@HwY/s4dnAlnd0x3CX7D9eitBNBSnfUJByhDu/KWVwEpQWFn33ahEfjy74j6Wt9cjwnNx4YLfN3NIybPfQliR7jDbRr4f72yl0h7a39G3/yAd/X57f2cRYmtFj/c3yAOI0J0uDgAkagwkdibgevLhA2gaZ17D6JjejyO7Z3i69LUXyqY071pdmed8c35@MVyMKLBGt91/l4gsRn4OqbJ@57B6eiJtL50tUftwWt9x/lSjLwvlANCL68Gg7aFT7h4oWyXGOxedPF7zxzKi3fxjxc4zpdJWuK01XqY5LQ@a5PjnKLWS7WX9xuoRYq48ZgZQBbDh8rhR/OI/7Cmdx/DjhwcSKWpx2077NEH78lh96dOXALHgiYaVSyeTixyyiJzjRLmtiHe0SrtNpTYh7ccHW/BOSECAGZy79M6Fovgw0NgMPdQoEwqutQza1mpovsy38gkQF5LEk5YheZCQqyKvB1s/9446VinrJ1mpMrIjMP3Aa2nzldksBLlpchDIx6URl6x6ErAeHJRmZ4GcXjHQ8ECrVfAbeZCV6bLzqHycFlNbPn@493T082j56dtjINC/946ZBISwLcgsOtX@c7YpQdp9sMHZwK8Z0zHkI2dHnAVA3dINyMSjZlaLVFoo2L5S4hWnWzy1LUejErSJdAn6SyHOjUBAE0YvDDkpM9eMftq7ww690hheqiIMWKU@oswrLLMt4rAMfXLf88KufOqFQ/BROBT@Ggxn7hmehYfdtu@vn6Brs9ivI8cH23qNnB7ssQHDeaM7MrjeolfPcLjG3AgD11DNpC1KNxf0kcairWi3@IA6EictxVqEz0mQTGNo5RAuog6er/dQbLLFO8IGC8bBSlP/6deUyLuNu2iTEjQdIxSFbaPLUUNbW1tgRNBJ2/2Dvs90Dhvjv3idvJBGCYEd4QPPPftzlVvUDOynBZ4CcEXEvskchRA9pByeX54erkebUdcerPwZEVuzpCHNoPj/8/ocg0NcVoN2ekYmzK@avkmSRhn@8yLdOFmRETSiwxI0Tt2hpzHHZqemaeIAaceih4a/Fxo57PcjYncy28UtH@D0lnT7xAKhPLI8b1/FNccSgpckhy0mzdUKWfxBCjESMb65BY28bMJ4x1wJt2PAq7BW0RJwcrfAD9pJUj19LEoCukEsaeKNhJOI1S2Gucuwo737tnyn9KgO3B@5v@@5p5h68/Yr/1gP3r3L3CwUb2nXLYnNcogihNUC/BByRkP5I@8gHnixu1GBOODSAFvBVZo6gmk6J6hid58DvErDjOZxE4zOoNGhuUGO@MQOen@E0E2iOsKIo2KRQxpJpK7kx5fu6rpglLOQLOVUBJKXTACDZEe/jgVUOMJmsQDcRTs1x7SUM4Jubm0xERcuoFaq8ZpV160VWfBkiug5xhbMBItdgkAaSzFNAWN1PBoNPSk1iUuRecTWOjKtrw6hE4Th64bvlE0JkCSAWp5GBhqmn@C0wz5kF5jXb@PWsyDcm1n1AkgpjErmSouCbAXhie9B8oJPOvyLDzQDgvkY@AqLdOpd/CY@sWmJ7lK/3rPnp1eBjFn5fk5EHcFDZzNXBNFq34nMEcYggKuKy5tt4wY69Y6up8LbJoJn@YEljtsD9y0p/RZvl5d6@btMwcdUiIRKL3T20bNQoH0BhWEJTtKyiFpLzIuVyS4vkl8jPBoqDFlUuIDtgU8AyOob5yh672zu7e1/Zf3p4zW4fxYxfjQZ8v76ZOpbkdKMZOuLRYi1Wyb0HyuHjew@CipgjXYhwY2D8fknUm0oynyhCkPODB1eLtgzDq6VbjfFzfjT5Kr5Z7SbUKNE1PNTMB@RLm3@lB3SE52rmWmkZtfL5m1Caw1MioHf4@ctrqCaS55eN5mb92IrFr7eEJR3hRUzewE4ArmN3Y13Bxn69cFiw8BuVR/gxKzfaF7PL@6K4nkXzUXj827NP5oazfI9IQKS8QTbAIgVZCaKu7H37XEafm3fT@Dc0uaGpqBmdCMKFzE0Uj4A6Cj7HiVxkbpzSt8s4AJVkaLaFwHwRt88YmJELTTNy00OJpOB/4oBnnPA/0DmtTGXa6ZNIIrcjWGl2k6nHAF5SgA6N0t3TCahCT@0xN3lNK7r3jcB1YAP7BUWVVEGDfWUygng9ehwYNLsOnFuCxEDJeIgql6WAS/iWHqcptKUJ@TXQ3qNfcHnUzSemSXlgTLtmH3h7IpkGjvaxqjZZaA0SC03WH624SHU2r4Ubu@IneKo2SvYPMgk6nSOgN3QZVE1jmoifxZOVJuSP/vGz56fxpLisLZFpUt9WZ/eqjdIQ/aJ6MyfRPb93BgZAl3GLcvk6lwC/q4C5Ea3gezvlsjxwBfp@Wg0l90PPeQROECMSvZE@ZomJxQ2QyYxeE8cJK02WmaQ6t2FosVSKFCp4UIDMKGWPXHz8TujWjCWUGjQC9HWtLj7emGPWUGW5CW7KJMnW8TtYOyBxoeW9pAA6MCSpENgaNiFQMwAj3klk3sAhDYZDXHiQGbclwfRZIJqEtJEmVGpWv8Mi3zVblBzFcrniV@giVywzaH3X2aGsANhrfC6Q64G6vm0SoBmov7IQmzPy6xwvRvnGOCIPfaMmgE4sYnc0sHXCANbcKmhn4OAvsWtBXwH5oFJ5dvSgVUoqIguNo/Qds4uT5Nx0dqji@R87gW6qLESNV7lG9wkmQzN0LW59Ba2hPaAOI15hqbEoGa5@dnjeNlX1xlbvJ/RrAWLmcADwD5G1AnBobzHYrrAkbDmz/9nP8MPGYmJdVU9azmkqns9U4aZW8yzPPl4/lqT1RqZ2d10HLcp7PT0GnVzZyN0/NQa99l5fORZFlmU5Rdk4P48/2HhqvtAKr6eXWbX0@mSsFhry62lTLNXSJ0329Onnb1tvk@L0dPZaPE5o9OHdnf0LUc2hoh@rlNn5ViEbOynjNyyZrudP2BT0VnbC3sB10mP4T@433YhbR3e794a@ARQXWez4GD9YLBZFRWnEm/BP6v5LuLji36jLdXmr@fZtsqHr3nTGTNMcu90u/OwBSJBa8pBBvneA01N8hR3TkxQoukbT3nweQc/Dra7hiUL5bgt9yKLhdNvo9ye7@sycPPAef/E8uJ7h9eZgyYREM5VKSFLjqnelpedjTMtof/aTtcv0@dPW5p99Y6QYa/jYx8e3Lx@j@1DNf7y29vG9e7lcWtM07n76xdOvbW9v5@6n808b@a2clFnb/NM/WVvTtE1NWWu6rtqMN05OPhe1TE6U/@xH8dbTp1913Xr2//j627qKtyLcTlkR@ARcWaaCE@8l@KkoY73vFXsTg1auxmb014oF/udrTK1vFf/bd/dfx7xYXVOeO/D0Yq9jhVKMO8EBb9ng7TRWj21itMJlbKbUajVwFv/bv4f09a8AHAyZbcKtng9gFWaxulSjJBexegEcqqZBvv/X178ewZCziRqJccF1lzXgEnNFTdxqwrVB16aARuekjKIE8Sxv4Bk2U0t31Dv4YsILPCwDjXQb3nEMvwjL9u8ydtBIpVJNuSXBJb/AOSJFVbVjVb0D3ED6eKNWkzYYt6qXzebvoAHgJM1o9W0YMI077Pk/xhVb5ln9QCAHQqywdvfl/XodipKtZzfqKbr8/kNdqVgSbfuuyNLsZRwUj0bz5SPeX1hdzJQ0MZ1O8040RQJJ03n7oS/Hx/gV@mBHZVf9FpJAFN839uHxYrt4/fn/@uff@/Pv0t/36Pef0Baf1TV7ygZEOoWOUIfrbqXSqdfFuiOeH@N7HVpPplKqlJTW5XFiA/hO84CpmU8u4vls/JBRB1IZO05Sargo27qfPb7XY3PvOvepR/38AB6ZPJhfCnIsUI3cIdWuxYMB1d@1KDVO600JxaCa1FAL@abEUwVY1suscReqSdSKZbFZ1/LaPlSdKvKKG6y7zI6BPlgI6OjjW5@XrR6GzN/qUa9YPUhWn8f50HgBunUh1mgoTYOGgcCP3V2rrJUqhYqmtELP6xerXvcyDOOpGzuNhRenTmxO0FjYNK/6BVURvrCgBbMPiSfEJIP9A18AfQuuNfijf7jCV7yvkY/vTVGuX2usom5oWSX/cWFX@8D8BRgeWKfdbr/ptHH019t6R1c9faJP9ZnutSftadvrTNCQzvuXSYi9bayxA86GmiwVXMepW69nstzyneSw8SdJ9jQmxP4RrrqqqWwDhqUM3EAWIyeoyvinqgKLncPVfLvReLsBPbSe2iT22KxLPpbwkFt3mynp8rIB7mrV/9@sh84qXdwFhWteplKbL@ogcbyoN1IA8oUPUuYw5Va9uUkBYV5@Zn7wZhNEFim12dis2Tv0gyRwSU0AuLmAZDxnxwv23bspGd7vQvr6epMlU6l1SVrD8bDhjxSQollPBUVCDBIgIZyf/5w/UO6gw15uXtYvG5uXl5ub8L9J90v/Cb6Xm9f@6TG/VsSZhzdZI6uVmshejhtK/Vg59plFE95lpY4@snIMjjo8IR7IFEJsg23E0LpaNrYhxF6@@/J/xt/xuy9/HyUtBn9GRYidY89QNlBPK3N1DW7Memyxx/yywI2/4BV90ONxHT0tfrNwKUdRXsqswmfLE2qpkJRxEGvZvRYe2JbZS4iKIg/wdiZqpYLYSqkzjcU2xUKRuPsvXrvi8fg/eamVi3E@sYHnjF@6rvs4gluIHXsMsataRpXUizq3pc2/bvCLy65/8ourLiF2UWZGBcjScRkniBCDWohJErD6@uYIN6Li0oKEWtxp7XPp2baE0w66RwtHHa5S1/Z2a@Vyna@KrD@lFrdxfwPuKvzvrkExhFj7Nf49eoN/7KiDfwev8Y8dvcG/Aw//2OM2/h29xr/tNv4djfDv3mv8e@zh37M@/h3/QjarVsX1cyJASi2rl@tTkQhRjW3Vj3@B104v/tPvfOMb8VotLsXpswo51XaYmqwCCV03Xr0bF2I1tq6uq5lhppNR22obHCbLOCwzyAzULkgWLZVlDJaZZWYsM7LVLrgM@MuAy8z0WKbPMlbGgogQCi6vlfHQ1YNHH/56AMiBPxM3R7XVTIdBRkMU4el7bAgeXBetY6HB4kx8aYB@JatyRi6YTfyKRUN8@fJY2Whq5RKTsWHIrcbL43gT7R1r5Rxrz4y145cs5oKCVo0px8cKn2qCshI5Li9brd0n91stBfnt8WN7f/6/vz@Kvt74P9q3H@/bIxv@9/f3oYEb9dTdlHQXrhpwKP@xFatXt44rxOACJhdTNreO61kJ3YUUMC4N/VIfeM0hwrO@dizEzxIoW5@heF19flY9rZL7LHgFR6s6jxBE4w7/CdcZ8PJA8D6D6/QMHfSGzrPnx6GLO5TnZ@D1nIFiEf6DAhN9/Qf4N//f9f/4GUuyRKOZTJxfbiboSuJfMnl@eX7p3@vJRMJ/SWzCH3rAOyY5v6yjkyKdg6uRSDaTl5fcD@6J5CYHWIdsNuuUdh4PmHcszJKy5bfEP@wTsvav43iV6fNNIsfH00wmWW0HZtpxyVO/oJX4ZJU@xbXebqjNP/0RmeLfSlKkfK5aVTcYf9FyWrWaC96KpWq1FLysJxLl61c9s6UWQKzO5ZLJahVetgKwGXgNwZYAbPCSB6iGq3d8Lni@t09G6oFL5GP4dQjOFhIZ@sQFfi0pLlbEO3cS/leYt7aTd@5o5czFRegzHoOXuuDVanVNp9VC/@zFhdgSac9GOQ/vmdLFhZopp9R40nYST/AzW5BVQlLZx1qdci0D89VyxeQ/jKQNwPKbm4VcvV7IgbtQwtXj6xdRg4nr8dh5MGQXk5w1xtcVscoVN@jdLl7s/DJG1c5y@WQCmGsSRKDLGP5xb7Vc5v5JliskSqmy/1dbA/0TRBH@h7Md2VRuo7hxF6Q7/JsuvZAnV8@NmnpZOzcqOGt8We34HznFw@HGnTvZMpC1lKkeC63W/e2j7VarJooiijNwQ0/i7gJ@W23sxBtU5flys4ElbB7H45XqXWoeainPoB348aQ4DBOsVCZCCGYPLT9A6QWuFayxNUGjJ96EMqfkGniC1I5Z468LF@uyNuvjxfo4/8dMNqSLDRkPp3unE0ay@eWHhq@UFq/QxwgvIfb00fbO7lFa25RYTHuwvZPWDp/di6n4mp@/U3AW3w92t@/vP4METx/tbh/ufrL32e6zp@DvsrP5FfB5/z5/Rl1L3s/Yc@GV80Y3DN2YGEbrbDI5e81emWbLhPobTqAQdt9hrtEC3Mf6vBxV@HVMV3/1SnfGdLF3P/jWux/8d@9@@J13P/zWux9@76dffu9b8Psx/L7Dn9/5d@U83n/65b/43Xe/80Pw/E/w@yP4/eSnX/7m1/mP3v8Yfv8l4vfH/i8Sj/8EgPUrP/3yuz/66Ze/@n34/Sv/9/3rv1/7yfLf9765@ofpvvu7N8f5zr@H3@9xWEHc7/wO98Pntfi/w@P96vff/cZ/4P9/6v@h84fvfuOP8ea//PPv/@l/efeN/6hppT/9t@@@@d133/zGu29@@903/6n27jf/rZqJ3n733ff@4K/@8Pf@6g//R/r/Md1/733@333/n//F//IX/9tf/KH/@wn8/gO4fvIX/xH6xt/@wQ/w/7t/8Ld/9AP8/5/@9d/@wa//7a/8G3L8Fnf83//q3/H7X//af/6b3/72X/3k63/z6z/5m9/6g7/633/1//zN//zX//3v//U/@wZ6/tZP/uqPfuUvv/Gtv/zmv/zLb3y54v6tG@9fvof/l/8IPu@P5/vAeZ9yfajPlz8XPn8fasxzgXYCrfuX3/3mL0ED/w3G3n3rx3iSAn4r/n@sqRTnx/zt/wMO7XqZMSQDLvj9@rtvfQdJ9D8AieA/pNe3w5eFEP7y7fkLkPW3lyT65Z9@@S9/RG8xo1KnhQgcrktaKbUBKs1GuewP2f4aBST5pUVoIQA/p28jh1oI@zbytnc/@Pq7H/3Tdz/4rXc/@BUcMKVcOb2dltRbJ9uk/HvEw4iF94mHET/H/FM0jSSlPoc39rkf@PnnnwutCwWP7Ny9AN/PyYtfjAfhkR4/KAhDfzzjwy5Y1O07M75z3fcNcyYsMNcUCRobgRSUz7JpykdoyvhiBfpDpOkGOad4J18Mngp4m//PnVOBpTAOv/DTYoGTHH46PwvuFPKQTWoaLpGQWMa4KLTBfWjJk/LNlRmWYDpNTUHfBQfkkIKgeylWq9VSmLDG8YFXjlq9xAiVVKoG5cbUPE26VUIQ03sEBVLWUgestVGb8oQphFcPyJES0OtAVDUxVardhwxr0/sMYSFwAvvyZa1eqk3rCO4tp0dqmrpHOCGwWmpafwvvNYIJ6YTY/beASqmWStVLmCEWkldPusUrKU@Fo7KnWMqvA3jizvWtu4x9LKolscWlQyQYj4331Dw2RoToEH6c2vCLQ/@Bk34bRPA1ysrPhfHwLRJEt7hsihEAriTJsszgh2vJW@wuBE85qBRlC48Uh5CiFkEtIPRgOO2TElJUvyl6gfxjtY0PvhAYFmZ9fV2I1cWsuC8T6RSFOScV2saPO9tQ8agwsVAW0dugMw0BLpC@Svmvx3G1KM44YPZxiv/u3t1gH0Mx6Tn3E5iUyto5O8ahbKZSogbw63ZKeAEaiADtlABdCPK0RkpOSkinGZNrMQxj@/v7PhLk8aImpKCZa1kV33GNZDKZxCCFLKfldNp/yvQkD9l3yBTqP@V1JC59ppZpWq4KilKVoReLajUqKMDo@fbtW6gV2ipU2QPdlPm7hrRciQLBg1ssGA5nwdkXLVcWuF7O1EKOsQRNfsKVZEmBJdhGUuAbzDkSwZWIa6VSnOIB9eXERrCJrKBSc8CJz1gdEQ0uriyW8skgcGef7ew/frz75GjcbDLBoM/uGq2xY3cM101g2PaT@/xwgVYuJGONBoI@qmjIYITdSobY3979g73DCuOF9qsgQYhVabHQL2ZZFWLj8fPNmL@JRsRPStniId4r87IltHIWksbqQqxjoEaBq8BV2jxRFR67/Xv2FFT@tCim1QKqcUma7mXC1@wJQ4OH3DoC9Ck8ciBvbhIFhPq5RDPy6ITaKgj1ur/9jKlC/XD3CBIc7TNVy8hC/XM2lTFD6VKoD2tDw@p7g3XcxyUeZ8RImdYbmTT@adks3NVcIa3mi821teG5hHkeU7Wd44a8S3g9l7AYH8HFhI8E9hF4wQV54C475m9x3Nuv@vvM0LRQgm82E9U8dLOkcAwVzcEJ48gFdIldWd8QYmtffOGxeh1UaWnvgRADbjFgwVYryezKA5mquTtxDArtM9Y1PzPxW2Fy13THQ30GXQeoEbu8vOwBpL0HTKtr9MpTdPF@2SGfNrgvp7oQsyqV2ls1VxS0k0rlbVbTBPAQNhTcy7UGDYAWxzcU/ld1IZNstqQAp1JFER7ZbFbAKWFBqBgCo30PbzO1msTbYDan0rYHnBpQ9GlNCy8/7vTjedxshsfFEAhgfc9hmSCsyMP8t4JAb0A03OhFHzut@p0zc@dOFucrsrlMODFBJWaXUDfr2VwWKS78/9eVi9ZcNsf1bEbdVMbg1MGZ21R0cLbBmd9U2uA0wVneVExwTupZNbOpTOoCEza5mUGGVgxqomdM0aop9xPrrjHsyXhgpiZSBpq46ZvtrQcJ691a1@7Qp4mrXdnET0Tj8USeIJcTq7aFBrBqeBSejmuyRPJc6NfO6IikYNT6MtpUcCx9KHTltt2dya43G@LRk6Ht1OIgEMaDgDl0AyQSnPDaymZzlQZrymN7vCVo@WKqoWZgKMGfWkpr6TVjq1isdOXO0NCdrXwlX0p38VSLvxC1lc9U@vLnjx899LzxgUFHXbZyZUiAVojQXshWqZLPNxsNUUw1KJsmfnGVMyppbQ16t6F3JXj2bMtzJa3UhMRd06nV4vGtrKpJaiWbKQmXc8IB5bCAdQFTprBgaST7uc8KKpZtAdeppPW0eU5EqPR6vcuN89T8RdDPJf4G5LmU9HT7PHytSpF4FTZJS@Y8EHz0HlD73F@Aq4haviRWG9X5e7EgVpuXwt2R0TV1POBynDm/nqoA3JlDjUFGx0y4rDi27VXaRs92jHnErFoIInKErkfIiZdhdscZzPH8enYFjAQ05JSDNs7NQdZpU2dDLeeau8BXGs3NwFAktu3Yixe6Xq9DhZ3niloun8tr2UIhX9Rg/CjnCvkSdJlMIZPXNACQK5fKxUtonUJM16V6LatlBU2TtKyUVSU1i/@3ODT8f//4GvxreIdUWU04QmsLT2BggsHUYo/w1LZnsyMbv9vRZ/eMzooYOwOdtr/uOLbr/j3i3NOtEx503@QmDsOghzp@vMgdmd5gRYxn4xEaajCcfzQIu6M2IIhshke4BzdnaNvLIhTZs6crSvk4NCoMxOBWhSH6wd4nD48iz6Pd7Z2HQoHd239y/8oj70fKs0e7D47C1yIPDZLmQxBf23306Oqr/8jtPzvoTWwHf8KD/We5@S30wtOVQg6uxUihNwHxb/hKohtO06@xfDFwqALuyb8D6ucd35kvzJ0ZdD7nR0dNN9wjzk8RV4Sj4DypzpCDtQ3W4fY4UB8mW1m@tKwWy4IwZpZ9xooZ1rWHQx2/xNxbA8@BjmfjDBQZh/Qhccz6zHaG3TOza6wJj/EYXlnFr94iEsJDADKadMgwDYgLaHmxi99IxnWh9nBisAl@n3yFJzzQC52O2R/A2HZmBxGEtq4z@H3oBemN6OXd7OHxPMjvWsjwenQhJojiQ93T78ZKwI3d5rieqVTu3FGfOmI5K7p9Y3cKDZY9gw6kO7N0KS96sviAya1YHxcMhgX1JJ@zx3W9DqJ@AwRjGBS3chqQtV7K5P/6t3/8d3/y62WtX1OP48eZnczjR8AeQVRkJA36EqNMuoNWLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLg9pVLIPknVFLaqGUL6vpUq4MA3yuDKH5ctGXN5VAwFQ2KgDW6uCHWDdJ/ZAHoGfwpUD2JqEnWUwP3ydMNCCNKKCm59FR4w2zBoMTUzMsW2QAUWcdFnvwYCfz4IEo3sMX3AKxkxHFLr7kS5lM8Z4oGhSyU0JhRbR5mhKatBI9/pLJ3NsRxQkHgNagRXGAL7sFnKsSRRNfdrYfPMB8eviiYXqIdsJD@MsweClCNAtfQAwmAK9DaBBtm@eTI0R38QWzxJAHPGQHwkTxkwAdDDng0TiAh0FJt7dFcY@/bG9jyA4VO88R/RRftukSRQdeoPWLYh8cfQf6nSi2wYl9QBQ74OrMdPDDj96iwWDL00VxxsmDBBLFKcXWOyei2Ar8MZvPfGzySN0Kvai81HfppYx/oqgFSGO0bPiSFcVc@JKDsj18@Jk@8LpGn18zhz87UNKHD7O6OZ3sPmh/8km73287s@3dTw4waGfnIcgHs4nT7rf9hO0WXDak2nmo6Sej2dULSr3XalX04dKgT1utnG5dCWrNWgZiCKleA2b@1ceMRq0dCNp52LqrL1uWJYAt7P4jeLbxujeC5z29zYOCi4LoOW23xSo2f5TC6VP00BPpq/Dpkd5x7Cq@T2trjMUT8fSsUcg0qxTARiBNZ6qX9A36BN51nFtJns8a01qmWZvWihrf0tNLiMdTLW@K6bXRllrOV9b0LVXLpaYVNHRg9@IsLqlbLKHe2XjDEk@SWxpI1uLx1pYkNtTmlqaWKoXii42JKCYreN/KFisQMRPPMIa3ZKPY3CrmI0mKxZSuaJViMVm9BHp4MJ63cc6jlUicGfpJMonoogYORaCyshmV06z2EtP0tMbxYrNkdVpTq9xGJstcg9VFg8yTjmc7HGIfwE23MhVcy06IarkkQv6KkkgmUTUm3VcR5vsGn3/16OTo6HPghEyo@zMDT/n3o6v@6ycPd@S9/eANDSnLD1CbsR15B9nVQgi38xt4HYFgLz@EARR0pMAPj5M59lDenXaMMapEQUBgHlP2jRrKRw8X4BwO7DOeM57Gr5JlLKtjMLQzbXaZXquDS@@yBGHF9OQZDd2ter3Wqo3owDoUMUj1KSMjzHMwey7HPbQRQMnP8YiVH9CqZS6r7do0NgU4rRqT1Jcju/tSS3WqXTQvfa92DxNXW/BsV42a4Ti2I8bEam/LqjE2sVy9Zzw1HLR@sbe/DoIEnrtK9JiRXGfHuxh7B8X/S6nuMGuO2ZPJKAEieTu56BV5RdIkvhoU@ZwOAuJWh8tqr8YSL5LV1/DqrLNEV76X3MpVu4l7rJUEn8zL3sse01ghV6XvviYQEnQiog2WWU/W6p@C7MMBn1QqgIhfxycAE3MCsGaXAvTk2LysdmpDlpDYlCWJPLlqv9bA1Bd425REsSlJjYumUJek50Id@ml1FtNr7qRN3yRgmbaqZQrVKfipxVx1ABWrv5hWndp44hjVIbz602T8vKNeBXIC1QDMm4vEu1/6enJTyte4X5VAXQxB3GjJrdq0aqGVM2gStWwNAlKNXCYNGjHcimkY5rVCWi2ks@lcWiqiL4zx6XwaPEGzAZEiMUyIjInpzDQjq2nVUNOJzEuz@zKZPkmAtEIkY8m0Z@9akxEDH6gkbJX0Ck@dJVPaxpBBLdhM35SomQKnqGLBgOYDNjbTAwR1YOhDSpFMSiy7kRiuJzDO@tFkvNtoViq70/FXISghvd4qpIqZ1JtksppYS9Zc47VQrwp15CpU6vEatFl/BpG5k1ED6hhcalGrNBptLGIxk85mslA6s3XR3xTrYjOdWSuoUEWXjMQjxjlGdFINhZy537iFEvfQgKpTy1pVkGmGK1vSpLKS38hn@CwbTymMfbaGlGSJYzE425uIx4taPJ6MV3F@f030J3SBlxEfiwNTjd9Rt0SQv8SKWNYwwpwl0vHNTIAdSGCXAs4msFxZiJ0Ll@eXm6AOK7QLEiRGtkYuSa7fFWIVxkAMPPatCSlrjH3o5srUZv0Ffx7jDnKAK5A5UpBAadOTYaIKxj7Dk@pbLA6I6c6ooWnZZkMrwkAGzDGICop4FZc0YrhFXa4Dhd1zwG8zVcdDXp@y2UxPScEc@x3G@ql1gcocu7psuV3b7h9sB1u6tndw2vYYZGyxGhdj5/FY/BL@hNhdOlmm8ZNlLBY5W8an7X8hfjcWj8dxfhwI9TZGPILtnAezWRX8OlZCr3CO0Ggm3z4xh@elrMQnJoBFXV7G1hWqmeBsz6cvNWgUMcsOPEAXwgkgGKzyeZx7jikvx@4XWin7eG/fuu88MBg/6lPKtcR6jGVUCU/MVCu@b15srZ2o0CayYvYkHWN3Y7RnXCyXNFHjHtUYO5HiaoUfDxofll8UX5RePH62/2z/gRA7XrtYs3GZgYVb4N5aX/kqRIxnc3HGjmuxaS1X9TfA1euSuqmhAa8iqwC776kFKXNR5826TgEFDULe/dL3c9PNErxrGRXeNS2f0up1dUNjydj43Ze/j7ZYznc/237E4jg5/Xd/8iOt@Hd/8q9pU1n8kiastWwxBjHRqRaKsfPz8fn5JVw8LB9rxjhSuWIS3HzxRI3VFVXLWpZVZRVF1zeKqZx216oqfly1qCZjrhTzl4GK@Zh74QdpmRIEBes05CUWsEpiuwdmXlPvbm5BcbayOa26hu1GDU8ksvBv03DLMSFWevzygjF46dS7/b6pkUtRWOWtxDbfSpvsLS6SvJXW2MtaHRfZVTzHGCwibOAJL1xIi9dTykacgR7E6o3L6mUzRcsQoDK@MIwN6/hKqz9ew@MJi14bFvwZGy79YaLAw4XX4M3YeOWKiY2konS7ocWvTYPl69AsNhTAbSNYSeB/knScfPdLv6lphb/7k1@7aF20PtdAcyyXC6oW@9nPNifWxDW69Z9BwhusbATaHy3DoDkMdIRaI@OGF00/VeiQO6CwTiwUk3n8QIdErRGFDLNvgeqPb8IpCkZUky1u6K2boGgbeAg/TWI2GVZKVgUhFEdJjHb6nTTBYBtomQ@6tnAufIRBMPqyGnBd4aM5KPAYwXhrd1rucOKM6TBHgtKpzTS7A0kgh4/Qht4aGQ/wWbcE7E7ZuJ6Uo@wS1UiIYiPDddEiH4w6wkeQxLdaOpyxsY52LjCmacFYIWMUwpMCug3Iuwl5D3mCFvkmqPQ8Qppx7HgiC0Rt4SOQHogKJggVzNyECFXgSx8BAaAMCR@w2WSbLJtk52YqVZ2b@7vEDe1o4FAPztgLmAyhddGmQ5C4ivHAC0R8/E4etgu/hkGei3gGQDgMviheAyUBk9MbSmlkBOO9QQEsMjiVoKKxO3fmWNVqZjfJqEQI/8Qc4wQX1YO1HFcAFihYH3crYpqhIcVq4Bs2O6B4itCFVidxC4rVSFIm4uulIMD/ezdabJFXqooCqlgAv754r@gAySAxkp3XYYdt1piqFZMsRL4DuHcIKTrqHGqNx9OPZe3zIPASMPxZLPgKBbCoo@ikod9urxpZYDBqTvATAGhqizMD3zgCN6aFrG7PC1KHqaAo5pBi90wHNBparQ/s@CWyahKTze0eEh60TV3L4QZvLZ/EB6XC2AyeOtqj8/NZIzs6HRsq1B3bFhmwIwM7uBMfWgTwKN/2F0d7Yp3hJ2P8uqHEUYxcsvuFLR8xJoN89K1dSovL5W0H1N6ANmlm9GXWGXWZVmYJamhko8wKwSUpESHcBvEYadweGiNA6dAw6HCVW1GUPkhXkzYZantsQrsaPDBhvLFcxf@ssXJmnpjKEZq8l@wensHiZi9iKJBh9@Mr875RtKFtn7CheWLwueDEgtEQl4GCADJuGig7/wFhK7jlQ8umWQaC0zwW/IrwKHJnKR1Ju5aYJa8/s@paooU1ekGDj@ngJ4tPdStCX7ouBF8ndmduYHaIjOfAuxyyXMM3OFKLoymB0JKO4BtQqpHtHhnXGMYJ0FADw0PoFMaOccpQuxVwjAGm2QlMeGAvhtJ@RAMA9T3oWWiP0HMqaHgGMHG6iQ50PZ/BW@xjltUEjMitQvkWnAAGVn1tETqEQVIsh@t1oWJkmlhHvgK9c9SFMDR54Dc/TB@0bnSTrch582ZrPjgcdCivGuPdInjJR16wd2B7pqKvQWABMFyCyVpCTAHYlJgUOegw/dXkvLULxEsq7DqkNEMIPqkBCokKwTfNWeTbLgIE3NNdbgDct1Z4dnYmkwnNiWPKhovfO3HxQ@3KuG@CSG0rnjEa@1@WNPGLwj7cuUvinzmSx4Px1hRl11r5zow/BaHn1vyNM4l4z43j4HiKn/Poj8jcFtq5cqlBPTDpU0CdhL@Ph7c/rZk@D9pfBdufVIpfIhDGEMw0PUt30gAs3e6cpHtn3aofcEodEoBDLRqBJxq2dYKXkRu4zHEvjGF7yEfDoPbwhBZcAZLI53DnWfMSBjFnwav/PjankMgyzti24@izBIUnMTY24MSMxB42g2GfQsAJwww751ZWzWlj1lxIPg2Tw6AWrv87aEtLOL8ZKDe5i@FTHj6F8CkPn84zDbJtTJtcJEOvSywOtno0wRjERDCzIM4lN087DyHIIH0zlYPAmLMFv0v4dWqUOqA3f4N6rAUNA9rEGAhuJJTGi@PGcdNyjbONZkrpQ2MXiRBQ4wC60SSannVDN1J/eDoc2@6Cl4WWN2FU8vFGr87Abw28rWAZwwqihsHpZaKxxP7I36jABQK/wAAB5TAIRNFg20uYyWpo4pkCoeE0xDmNOWINH5kmSV9@kO8H4hInPSdsFFAzAgj9wyIBmhDCgp7Dv24VcIfnjg1xgrgSfZBnhEa74s04UPJKV@G8pkqVFMFKkgI0gewortauFiUIh6poXAmKFPPSr/8o@msfjH4P@sVy7KnB8gGjKkS7Cu4SBBHC7y5EVVavReoVMFA29KHhwMi1y@VTf7SGbDaUQM3g@WAR3DP8ZHciUvmdJK8fOokoWmIlbAqzWg2KOKvxbsn7RUBSTvAwmesnmwUNwU/PGQjAyCxNZvjJptFk01qNMw42XZHsLILklJCc8iQ89nQFkk0/GWhPe8HwgtXTBOkUtzGKAE/lwyiIQWOR4Xe7cdn7FRoUxMVSP885z6FW4LchFLGxnXWaS3NvRJCOMK0rALAhXgPQ5R/KrAhXGZ4qhW8hj@KkDHgUf/ObAecV0MCIBVe50d1E2MhIBwaBX0zROAB9V0w1BFGliWD8y/CfmA48g5963TOzGFNd9Mykr/z9o3g2kbKRDhqRPtRMDhkyajLPLN9aZVTmiOE3pQc2SHXtM5sllgjb4K9M/KRKe2i3lZGO21fw83n@J@XHs2SgP@AiCrs7tj3ds3O5CleaTGp2y/LnOoPZt2z86kbE8DbIel3bcK24B5XasfuW6RpphjYRTwxf7TD8LwsIUTnZd9quIPhTmFyNRdC8XaGo22rhB31brQTu@0tWwu3MtA0Qm2c8LqD@C65IemBPPtD9ccJuvzI6XvJ2mGhF3k92ZHZOEvtjPxCnW7cZ8LAOyP8QOgAJhrn2XHMkC9UoSre9BH16YmCP7D5IfRNXFjD1FfB7c9iIkD4eEy5ppqNKW4l8S4B6SaKT1pN@0k8/OCn7VEvoyTC9tghggRhp5lylMVLWWZJda2V2PFmQ3@GH43sYxffwZnxJC7@KM1fNazzww7LOJuYQIOIcjeztaGDRgW91r6GzgErojXIVT/DeKHZpe1gXMd2GqNt@dLkH7SMdvrnwFiL@2Sr631yBQfLd960@Hb9yfjgDfjPCbY8J@lCSG6yGJiD6XhJ5z/XswqZ9/z3zgrj4jboHKEKAGEuMy0LjutAxx6B2u@F0cQD4ljaPO7KutXvaplXjgUtwck7T7ERbXUX3W11jqM@MbsKPmY7ADUp8AAob8av3KzgyOmJ6Ntf1EjB2JcNQGMaR6DxSZUWT0dOnyeTqZsWjmGHroZlywnBvNf0w/Bprxim@Gp@tBj0gHo/hdOypidOf49l4xu23D/nncnw@yscfXpNobuF2ggAd@OippufZJm9inweJsEjvMSKEceXFIqN55QAimhC6XocfRqLbSwqVG0lUC2pZWPxyyfIaN2@q8UirCNokX2Z6vyZ5W6N77zYXaWoc2JyF7XzYEHINMm7g6HQSUYjc58Yas61rPAH9aJ7OWjGqtJYw1DAlcTrPJHWb5IukgJrxHjxxwukzeCLAvuG1eIMKyoZzWv6H5xiFjPRxRGrxfUBIBygRKnKS@2hEYgmBG6KfX4Z5dlbm2bmWZ2chz7AHLGYZiSR0FrL0awGr56YqGBo9bwV3xiDUneFxE9uGy7J1B2crzuNmvGKmWfw0XgGGHDfild0EMOV4N165Tw43Xjkkx0m88ik45n0rfhGvBN0CIzjwSo676O@zcHzvxCs7ieSl4OknhhvkK8crYZ1CnC3@ShQBUmC5QWrEJTbL9ovpOQYMbCRUphm2GDeN6hPNw6Tpl4F//i0i@koJBuIc5wZFZimmLgwakRGD5wPDRmAFf0lPrvij@e7@A9oAFUbBbFKg40XTEHgQw2PxRWbEEcNQWtGAJyCIfLOyHCMWGcneEx0/d2ihVMmL@RP1ZJIHugkKb0Dk5jwT@gCVnz6or0UQvALfD09MvArPa@gE2RFGuCabXIIWEvVl/IZCYV0v4uLXfrSGaK57MRJgKwVReC0R2AhPBxmOFucws7E9XmwkFIqb7M1oGpqU450SW@@VZMQV/J65Ipi8/ZIhY4h2/uRNxYmkQ9QWWBAGNjJN3svCcYF4MQbNeV1EUuWdD1CI8Bzo4UbnhD7udd93UjzObtI0VqwahoK0PEviXItsEhLLaL9qons891B53UWrVh@mvgYppzjXkkAAkZRhLpy/2h8gv9tcfg8E6oAIVzJYJlgvH0qvi9c3jrJXMB/Os71egRiYZveTS4WjMIc5yUE7iEjmN7W1ayI@bvngQj7PNIR@RdoPyBbqBLfQ7apuwWGhlOCcLnqeaOB5oq0m1HWJZHgqB0KLjDn5cHjBQ0znRbsZV17wZVWMITS/rQ8/uIKdxQqOVh7CowI4V0jOe7kzsWiXy7xvA9vmPshS1QrjjJyWS8NqnnsCu6el23DZFjz2Wwf39588@hoMusViMemP0bM5fthrca41HMc5ZNpNHY4HS9QWLY1f4MHFbpyOdwe2460dW@I1XsKZNQgDOuQSND@/jyd9Xhbh51f6LqTjcSMU9WGdzLuBvsCVUNTRccg2fbp6QBDDS2zoPpBAvAV6p0lbS9K3ZlotSx8ZrRYNX60Wbl5qtfxRDKsmWBFP/iy2pkxchz5cyz@UdCYIZKiB3d9nzx9uH7Gjh7vswbOdT9nX9p@x59tPjvCM/tNn9x7t7TD47T453GXCwjZL/KgcKpRA1/tGx8AvhTItk8kxgrxjj2ec7yR2ktz/UB@xh3bHwGWqTVcf3R3wF9kyvDpPtQvq6AznME36iODI9HC/BX31DtRYFG66dDAQN/8ziNsGnXaEOu/I7po9E@IKqPuOzf@nuGvdamNZzr@Zp2hL2GhgdMMGYwthCxC2TjD4cLG3F2BtIY1g9haStkaAZJu9TvIjL5D8zyPkVfIO@ZWnSOqr6p7pEQLj46x1vJbRzHR3dXV1dfWtLn5obMlUJ6AeJHlrzJQ9WSQhwB2rDnHgSmhgXVPxBuXH3Q2BaYj@FUiMHBIRr5VTmnDRvx@m4EF1792@gruHjd2dzdpBbXdnX23t7tHr@0@1nTdEz9r@wV5t/RBJnPHd7mZtq7ZR4Q@CQCGn4Ifht8tweC8KOWRnqjR/x813rk/dH70lT72xglfXDTaRDNXcZRfSJ2h0gi9@a67kXIZYvsAsk68KVGa2svfmA835yv8DN5zmKpj1D1KHIQddnC2oVa6NBssajbeSYxwrZrJFl@8jLsYKcVf8EvtnyPCzpwxwVuJpBb5KbUBHBWff4saBx7IBTRU9ItgAZRRWyorjJc3NeasMco1qa3Z68LgptYkSoX5B0ddG1aTkMMW0rgyAwsCh1sV5ULEUfSC@pw@LutrhQDKop9EHyaCeyQcsRWvQHVFLOsflcPcS4lkty4ffLvpbfC2snkcf1hu8i13ROEm/cZc2VBRvDk4tOhwVS055OHJnI2wGARcJOT8iRnU6MjB8iVVIMlGuElm3jXKmSNi0cdWg1d4kBDBSiRugJ9RoD0OVKbs5dQDlIL8bSDyys06jKypQseoO855agf@g8ppePkRxvNhkpN9jBkQMwSQeUblNvSr0H1qOSq7fqrGhdSQ5lqZRQfseAuu3EPh7wBCgbGKn0@SZiq1WAabX1qycCXvEkTi3/dPOT@zcumz6iQJaayvzW/Dli6uJ7CX2SUZPkbGjLvriD2hZyVeZ7d6AxjiLVY58BCnYPO/1h4H0YSbZAr5x4mmOcmNio9p@NcTVtYEOkzV2e12r0lPi4jtqPSWmfEitzPFydx6JrzgkLnE@TcKidwd0Gqe9K9@6O/NwiXTt4/iFFsJ8V47Dz/GQMZH1pxPLjj8VImmulNc214@zf/7qIZymiAWJZmuUDvGfGBN10fDgez5WWBxg3aVHmgmDFl6eorTWwdPSEqPcAKN94HlA@7rX9VKUJurGt7/DqGbyO3/89q0spbKQTDoEcnieiaWbp45MlR6XOVFaBcSSnYQsyfqM@eIxzEhev4YhDXoBDnG6kCPYt08EGdMixLTu9LJNkkXHetXdHcF31RprVMSBsmEgY/dH/nNmvbyw5uZjhRJlkTNjRLRnIBdd11JL4fnqFrjN@8GR/H44uJV7sZPp4Yegbd4L7Ydwyy7cDUumJQvWw8H@eQ9Ymdz@LrDUdu9uwDJJ3oYWcXrEnN5sOtKmvb/GX2/1HY89AoO5FycoEVCrtssuX1EbB9cZKeDaYOIF0f7BZnVvT6Vkf0JlSe5hy9DSYhCwH6n3sbZt0GVhl4sWTbZXalk8mS8JjTbz777BPJV4d4gKvQbxND0iYRFHrWkHI5F6embhJQRr37NANJRLYvfVyKDwSAO@oT0gIRt3mtVAZ2oz0zL5BKGtBK7p5sna2NbhZw1rmbsRQXUwtgHZOkGNM1iWTO@/j7I@fmnqkQUWfAehwS1aSdN8Q/uEfaq4TxlzuWQP3tMtpkuhZC8L7LShHRS/CskV9s8zFDOSLMJlLWyJdb041qjJ@njWLHNYIRHTQAOanjpRNJopwYh4/rJqd6gbT3qZ5BREi0zE1HxtcwUVP7nRUxhTI5ony9GC3B5rs4zNkcHyBKezGnbp7kyPoQu9PCkeJqsiaXtvVdn/n6pklkjUZGg@tTEmkSAvLy09/R7syVaY4tmfhS1zyKT8HF70aX8fgwzHIR/vE@fWdjyTHjPAPaQT1XozYCYK0lJnypySaDtPRjZ@hIucCxEycPeOMKWTtbpqNIHbdOgyI9nQOcutNlhDOGqojJpb1L@5vzoI5O/W9@jH65PBhkxQHbyBVv673iD0Y6s8y5mL9Qnmr8lv/mDQ5Wxiz3QBKBk2Y7rX2I6t7UThVVqFRL5vs1vS1tZJonbrmbMGroSPF3OITIzTvdLk8V62WLKbulXbrqp5dgPZTpxFpgYp15I9j4LufQiwDOZzCUwfbMP3OHxJ/wkHz4AkMrE1X4Zp434XN6YIrZqPONyPVgvVsrU42fvtsNnowgeIl3ocqpT3hAryKWx1d8uddrJeKCXKE3Jhv5uhUl4qm0txUfqGA11ASoKQ3sR3a8KCpYbRlIR5zVkP@lG42PJHcnrGmpONfHGlsPzC4dZ1vaF3cfTixJtvllOKJt9G9yK8HFy3fj/rnV@1VUf1fzsdNcdf/lBq6Zl6SnUtPhFfvMXlcp7dnz6nvyvqRYE5VyP4iv0KI1JuTkKIKjWn4n146ZGSQCK8aX4JC4kJLlXzF4YLYWI3LF8cLZ@Uu@VC6eKoe1KCkd9woTxcKC5k8OEJzaIkY@Rm/mh4gjnVPnX1u1cKHi85aKU2DVFsGkJf3jUGQW@7svMmcRqHBQCOwLSuNx@oS1TiGWizwfYk1/WvM/qYzFPgWAcLJGeGrYKKsI3n82Qcx7QCwox6xaPVbDjiv2PXmSnkLvvDHqcYr4ZgLfUt@ObMGDOmAp8oUJajwPg@hH0BwYnzZHAxJF/HokWdLcpyrQjbSdcCcYSSLA5Tx6kUbAqBqLblOjpxwpzfaJ4DCYTh/sbF1OoqB@UmVgtzfIoHVY7GgA0mCid4xAUI/fT5tgFV8Mo9ZLMPh5qP9yIe5AufUQ3ZToYV5B1eKSIF6t/qK9s3cflVIoAQfkbWXDl9xKlXXrSQFNtBPlyAa7Pkxh/XDDCrlE6ZQWMBW@orx8BZU5xphGo1mej7zDXIKbSif7oF2SK/3WpGlN@V7EwSvqfWbyFoyV3KSWv46cTFMlaxrClmMlukmPkuNXDSRdujdz4Nq7Ha8DsdQlpoMROTA49s36vrX4jqD49Q50mEvKRnb6VnE@k5SRek4lw5muDjTC/tTKn01zjfjUrF2bxbdZUVL15y1NPNHC1J4ryl@/KGuWGvHsSZ16KuFK6MElYTCVkr5fOU3peUR4kyEYNH6UeSrvl7Ufd8hGUi7@tk/fh1dAf5rDyrdU0muDTXDTqvHB3BWaeAzVJETaWkOAcaVGZQlbUNphYntILDOT8P27VyDGWhaCQOj5nU2urrVE4vMl5lJtEQK8ZbA2vKGLGoxHUuMOFGbLBI9XDyIwsEwwSjKTNy10zhsS48tsAi1yNTrVhB3hrg1LTJIV6GXeQ3/DGDPYmcyZeenjgjmI@k8WLdnCQQC91HqelkSkoTmIvIR92oe2aRuO7xJMTpQmLHOgWO6vTFBruNY/BHkZywBYWRFLfoHqVoSscZioZ97@pCJN44/5ufd940aI3d7/gjVcE2o8FWWE7CwH3oh8MQzqDYp0142e93cOvIC75rNqHWfkUWl3DdEkO0ZvacU4Nmj@T38KQN0qlQTu0C8jUUROKE8PLsDMZksIDtXUO04sQlGOacSncsBxo0Zp4uipm5r@B8gwVwJzizkZCek9EDSof9RtPPObRGC2n140hT24EO0Mnn6bAbgbsxmtJeOs5fL4Pm7xtvcJ/7vFh4WrRIdqWvgwu5p89iAysikklYhKvApeIzx7HuhptyN5wFQE9tY6L/QLzpX/ndru9UaMbgjCEtWkN/cOW3co6z50eXwIALVsbNJOywe5eDphzu0KKrQcwIK@HQk@sw4jD8Yn6W6@Im35V5Di6t4ttm6uqroAUCGouTdg@3w3xhATcBQg8UuvCHRJR5VyVR4rtnjQuvXS5wEEXUgJ8T624iIkO3Nwya1DN8kuV0CJRcg8SVdVsTmFB9zU4DxsG5aQjAPCamgEHAXCXdh4OjL81/CAelG2bu2BumZ/Ik/Xo8Vmi4@4OApG9MYO4VLmbhTh188La2r/Z3tw4@Vvaqip7f7@1@qG1WN9X6J77jxkU5@91Vb3e3SbpEt@lya75LH1KVfSqZ4gSnsvNJVX95v1fd31e7e6r27v12jaAR@L3KzkGtuu@p2s7G9uEm374TBLWze6C2a@9qB5TtYNfjWk0xJy6ndrfUu@rexlt6razXtmsHn7jGrdrBDirDrX5Fva/sHdQ2Drcre@r94d773f2qQsOczdr@xnal9q66maP6qU5V/VDdOVD7byvb2xMN3f24U91TrCRgtXK9SlhW1mkLi5q4nZu1verGARoUP20Q8QjBbU/tv69u1PBQ/aVKzansffI00P3qXw8pEyWqzcq7yhtqnJP5DlWoXzYO96pwlwRK7B@u7x/UDg4PqurN7u4m03q/uvehtlHdLylne3efCXa4X/UUohFy1QSDqEXp9Lx@uF9jutV2DmjOOHwPfQeXOvkjEYawrFDRTSYw1CDQWiLS7t4nQAUduAM89fFtlb7vgaZMrQqoAI2KjQM7G1VIRDywm6l2qm@2a2@qOxtVJO8CzMfaftWlDqvtI0MNChmfiHWo0kNuNfqJ8JJHYlbHcK7H3alqW6qy@aEGzHVu4oD9muYWJtvGW03zHJzyWocoQQ9nBo0L@2ClffvTlQ9vlLdPZKaf0UQekzZ2N6s0I2vfVqk44ZBmnZUJV0p2Gs00USK9JlzWtPzTy7N60G33YGMaFZODj4vwzEPgHRdRS46de@JO6fMVLpBO1@sfKnXa6O7X6673kJIJNL5XQh@D35fL1W1ELAPsvHHw8/Kl0H01Qai1J/qikxX1cAGBnEL9J6L61rjwXZXPt3xdDMb7AGyOjkK5NjnHVQqJRjZ2RLiVuEo@meD3QLMDF8wY8LlmHeek0IzkTL2Q/nS/xS8yOVgfSDrLcVc@j00soxF88U01Ugm7ROA/2iNB0OYqc6Hv/36WKdjVYc@fO@v1WhnXNWU475D2gWcZ9zvFT/2zieLZyfKMLF8760ABodl38xImun/WJFO6X3IDblkGf@pD/nENNuLzAaemXBUfVutDy8wTKQ6NJE9p1xYwr@BOxprvXeWX2kfs5gqLz0oT399G32VsQV8QXmtpwjvicif88/ZEMtAAY18cRJJAe8jI560yRt8kynxNGc@R6TpoQfOH5upzn@d1IgktZC8bHbtOzMaDYGRjT3L4zV7l3frh1haJTmD7bGXp@XLJidxu/eLJ7yfUw65l2etYn@ZxWqdxkjVKNmjhwyPFcukdsz8zcD6PjPDXbjqNP8LPQ6S3kdRkgiBDc0PEHupCRS/lgw4pxQ44HjmGX6eOTM0AmURTXbTmojHiJX6D1krMA1qZpTPmXhvhD2BHw98M8ahBmoE0i7GzXeJc2l2w3EttGVVR3tyw4x5kyaUMH4sbt4gGfNTF@rOwruU3zdtWL4aiyojxyt3OJQmJR5NYKKNX0ZWR/Z79jOgDYPYeRl9@0fxGj5@0gzt2d9cIh5XhPpFxKyqJc@r4MFo3@khDPkHsDDhVMzWtKpzyuxopHnv6ODlyDGKNBkYFQVag45sEXIr8iExWyRqwr@dc9VU4Fc47AKekOVa/E@dOa46GUjL@Q/S78UqhBFbk5ESodh3V4ZgsnyI/FoacCTL9FD0Y/j@QJlPgr9KOk6DH1LKcAD6IkgxVaEXbVyZKcG0uGqzbjZia9qdPMZgbu2POo4bp25uR2NcQCXTvjM2HT@z2sJ2ZQgAwOQ427PEbqaSdN2jr9Drl6uK4J@k2L/oZpecKM1XcgptdPvF42eWZuxW8uMqVsyarwm0qql7Lxu2URz1tmSa28upxmBJwrvH/kZ/nA5BowDOXnovW6iRnFfQoM3JAu1qyJpxW5DGJlqU3d97azSvLRWZC9uubL0MoAr0GfG63kwOJ9JSo5yY9LvJMrA7YCx4ciGObjMlHu6w7ZUXMjg84j1t8GIJYI8NrTBAdgc6u@mJoKvOYFUVQSax1GPsZhLh1c0RanlavI@z5ZBIcGmF/2BXP9b6capkcOXHwoTG0zeVz6l1jTCh3HtZsYbH8/H7Pg@4iKpNjCV0ecVWavd6Alo4NtJtw9IKxm1Mf9aGD3w0vB9p/Ic1nwUCfSJhFP1WDZZPs3nmaEafxjFoYDGGt0Moxf3CTLnxoiIp7klF2WWWIeQ2PrplDx2C0UFSZ1ThllWjCbkmZiKtqWX37JrmEoNplqM8UDMJoc8E6m1wP7h2i4XfdG/yOuR9LoG7Lb0WeSS2QfBYonVTrso/H5lCa3u@FfKJBXYETkIgSRTlIixRVaY5@rtlJ6zWlYu@Y8F3KLfnxeiImNdpSVFHMuLp2Yr7lLHUmqLSoXYNGzkKLi0uMyrQN182dmzH2Fpq8tlap424kUl7KIqL82Cwd8SRyM3r6hCd9yF9@HGL00BfcceslKBDGmhX3qrflHOMHnYKPgT9o2WeitJJpNfo4fuOtT6/LvGiODrXbv2ZjGPpj2gE088EozzDqmb/0zrv1jV6ncRb0ggbt0@D3fSQSD49jfkSHnQ161yGHDOKElpWpNY6fxb@MuGHDe3QvWbJcc4VDv5@x1RSGg3HlXNxE8Mk5lADjgKDM3/1JH2lRmWdLcSEnaX/K@nhFt3Rn2afFaYXlRh8AtIBbm9CgEBvSIRsmWcanpVsZTu/LYOF4qrKq4d6hsZfA@AWRiK9hEhgbZG6pJdiNwM7sToyPWiOvxT4IB3C05G/6iH0TZviz10CMZZIir6Ap8FIVVwpWUblFGcEPIR7Gd5N78fk/GHtC4CfQLz6dxi3TGIFFXNt4Wwplv6K9jBIurB4YsIxmSUxSLDgLupb5IUedGE1CTSaP76IGa/7Qoki72bvFlRiRGdr4ILJdpk4ipz52ManMqTmX/XZgCVIZZgp3M6z/Pf1ZHvy4xJWTMwimDQ05YyF9F6maRCVEsZ1Qr7VRFp/K3x8xi4sP7bUJApanqZxZ0ZQzKbNyYQuUQOZXXGv1BiSMUxPU06oec@Gw1597IPXulB1TPbNNo3XTdb@rCCzMVqbJcr7FpC2P8TguOZP4TDBNkmKsaUY8hO0rP0dsPknEUbmO8Vauj79Dh7toFutNRZNK1N8tGfuYFK@g0WsmmmhIMe5wUlqKvh/VqeH1uyWIhinbqzpLjDpERn0sjxaoCTJFVHo4hZj7NO4T9GgR5VBvi2hn98@dRJ1UkjMuT01Swskl6AnH7TDaJLnUb0P5Am7iZIUbCalowTnyxnyVV8yewskwEgQgVsV@Nj6HkhPcuLMm@IijA7QzdWgLFSGJ6GnN1nCInP5HBGOv/PpwR2s81MfZ4klJII0iSLSr4Fz3QTL25vR6VB8xlFukoCE@hRRRi27JpvOHt@pn20L5CIKU5mSt6Vvw0BhXLRA29MdOqo@wBo6r0iUTIyo5EOosGmgs0C7lrOPLdhWrv2AgHA/tBj2MaAMhnzP4WdAl4M57uRBRG0VGrTGyuJrcMtpclV2TIjFDyTvIr4eiLHV540oAfMGYypeLBAFuTRl7XAqw6x2b8xKI6j6iguUihiV9ZK@osZ7nlHQQVWd4tmTlKEzL8cKGkZ0KhBYW0/PEiNCaZXqWGApNdFNxsXI8n96eOActiA3vC8WpK3SvJGkY9ZwQkIM2F9xYohwVlVfQHMyJz5bcRGLE35z6omClFiZTiT4RhkfZ4mTqSiGRmqh2cTFZNFGS6OHatSYSiRSujXAkFX7uH5um2C7PI51Qa5ORWGVo/WwE1aZdJu3bcr@FapWNss0aw8CzLcPN9qsuIVYSTtnvd8Cu5vjKAL7bf7q1RjPVYKJjBbBfOmPskpENIa9YU5jq0SzsdI2nvchBgdnT9trqw8HWVsLt6@nYKBpd@IOlQqEAJj61nd8b3WocJQW9fDJ3vn3Z6eT7138ZfDjNs@z3fQ4J8NLsoH3qEhoUYa43OJPIEMCBsiJ3VhuyYq9/2W7bIRhwQ4nOo26TnNobguIJKIiUXj4c8AEQg9QT7K9oINr3q4pG33VDFpoairmGotJQCb5KmdszIg8@tKGfHd1UMTAIZqPNRPOWW177ihkEkU24s9h9sfs1Vk9OvfU7nZ6nPiLoMDwFzNxMFtjasgsUJAtuGNm69zJkf7Se8q@CjmVXjCw2rwOcmZhMnAnjFx6@8ff8s@qon0kdfU7RtEJNXkAzF@Cf2lOps5SrncU/AKzwIaH9oNwXjX6myXSazExTvR7B8RNh9LToTd37JLK4fCamafb93CDqdHRz7KyBmu7yWsD4sufu5ZbckT0ibup4VGyDhgWBoXGCz5WHlYCp2T9OLF4N2@2HSUUOAyAd@0MSUSKh/JxA5DsAHoF6@BE94UX7n7I0rLcmHIrIAgfBOm7LHRSoo4DjPG6W/7jOVCoVNdtfWFCVyjo9ZLOqsl5Rm/iwvq426X0d70/Ki0tLJZG5m@5X@rhuPt6odYLBJ5wLzfPBJr1SWhl2Y9DWRhfP5suzXmm2Xl5dK4X5o8o6zPrp6b//@V//@1/@LV/RL/@Bl3V@OfocZcrlcvnZ5tfZJzclvB9tnszNnh7N9k/mzkrgsv9lr@G92jDbiNVHc4NTJy2zgPWV9UjNPpu9z@iiygQFvGgMfifp8lKlm2E@rb@GEjmKZWy66VvffdhRntIW3gQdmNzKExJpAjrGcTz1TtOHAh7NN0RJwgV6oFJe7lbMwT3cwUQZoluVtPbEw2vWKx82LbEnBdji0oyVDbqh38UJ@BWveaV5jtOg32BY1/yb//wuPFvvjdT8cUbNF9S8p@ZTKf4pLr@gr@5sPoB1rmSj7UAq5VFKfLUANUMVBrzQ4/0Dx9qZILfjzHLIHkAybio4s1jBedHuj41lJOBaeObMIPamkiMSvmRCkfTX2e4NdctXynGTSpja8EKhrncxXJl1oxL1L5ZAjVAUAeKaL4QgL3tUJW762CIZT3nzRfe1w9GEGDDIuvdmi8c9PtBcNNvVOs@JvRTCHLH6vHzF3FgSY2hGGylSf4wAX6jIdrLAloRz6TlHtLytVnIzxQrbbp9mPtF1GPtDo5suhf5UFhOINrdNuNmutmvRitxyvaJSQXS9YlWVmtT9Vo5V5OKyMwz62lyBa8eA@hrVdiMjCT3KgASO@Ox/eXuE8UGB8RQ10S0SLGusWj00XUZCV5umUwe7Obk5soiQ/5yhsf1tYmy7ebYSMewgPMBIRap87UbQCbXXlQET@6wxOEV0wEabA6oN5d6Mz/MQbnUC4147QjrHkFnlPB7P1JR0f9A4u2h4Kr3TOxg0xjWatmjlM2zmXGohXDABCQw@XfW05hmEpUW6S5giUVNYcwjBCzpjHR5N@jYV2ZygS81Q0G5XMAgS7MSU9L8l@mqCjjFX/0An2CjfEt7RbaQWsSx5oWmkIaVssxkeZreGjmNqsMdONHBSjqAajUzDC7rQJSbaC774JUnegY8AXXdKWwFqU4TlF6gfs9OZ320kJqd@xzGG/vmSknkR45lDUYo2kmMCpRbjiHfAitaRn5NeIGRuMu6MnJlMZuY41OHc0vY8wk6@I138fEMFUQA6DmDGliHqsBuIsJyYoeIYGDlVY81/gtDuNM4Iv/F1YwxWPE5nXj3Ku0efj7sn85nj7rfjLy5jokWymWWzKq0vs43E0mOFZsa8l3g1WmmhcTV43E1mOO4qsWGxSECI5DNHn/Mn3/KE0HEaQeiP00KQRJcBk/z99eUBPn8LzXQSi3zamXHnXdP5mVdFV9Hcyr/oQ/ngyi9hYTaVfExP@5xBm0Cxne4fl2JyEuZXFgvPFovPaCd05o@yA/8S8202vDz1R7SUCLGdpann@EuCGxKEuBmFjRJ9HFE7JayJ2J6E2khJi1A9zLkeJ2IrKpMTnqD8RGV2lwoTFzfK08DlIzb8niKWM3nZF5SoDlrcl8H8GfYuUE8jhFybtA4RjoSWgeiI8BFqFpBN8JW7ONQ1w2WO7ZxyagO@WxkIdW8@bc0W3V43qxdrbm6uhEU0rGY6K4WVwuQYvTVEEyN0Vi@m5h6p4tqr5//177t/pIfptcX8xwH9DtN/pJdX0vJID/T21LxdpdfSq8i2fJMe52kPTI/P/@s/qfzaXwgOUsar9GdtycBaHqfXsmUu8i29tkwPxcVFqvd//vY3asOs7NgQi3W27ilGrGQostHoMu9SuqqhlbItnYvFChtmAYZoGNLenF6gGDVaXCnwMV1aa1Vc@drzldFH0VM8K2YNWVVITjKMPgWtjKRAGRVkBaRRoWgrS3fDqG2AeWM01a@Pc8sh7QB@1eocUZWR6sbjECpDs7Itog7MSI20n5eHtcKrVKTe8TJldEpKZgmJrZ2WtStPS/8H)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/iynr9)

I test polyglot.htm with [scapp.exe](https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-js-sdk/blob/f0b4b184/bin/windows/x32/scapp.exe).

JavaScript code is now this:

```js
d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function(){...}
```

Sciter.JS executes scripts after entire page is loaded. `window.onload` is not special, it is not called.
In Sciter.JS `document === document.documentElement` ([link](https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-js-sdk/blob/f0b4b184/docs/md/Document.md#class-document)),
so `document.innerHTML` can be used to change page contents.
`<p>` is a workaround for the bug mentioned in [answer 301](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224346) (like in answer 302).

Answer (score 3):

## 345. HTML+CSS ([litehtml](https://github.com/litehtml/litehtml)), 15614 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
pppppppppppp ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8;[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl6154op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92g=1\'\0C0ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40XHh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt1S36pStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKJMACQIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3i2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HbGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr7uBnP4vhxZ7aw1l/aHvMM1yPdR3z1HBkdm/G7uqmm9eygoCxtp3@ZGRYnlsRYkxlbKhb/YneN1jPHHqGk2auYbC2MbTPIFxjbHNiTVyjW4e3LGOWccb2rI7ZBQjMs08My3xjOBCWY@y@MbwYXXisY49GutV12dgxLY9C84w91eGlN@mcML3teo7e8UzbgqACY8@soT5qd3VG0ceOwRMVGYDqnFCaxZASY49txzUgB7tjuK6NnmXw1B3TfrT95JMr8dUM@0QHpMZDY3ole1Vlz03D6V5NobHPjh48uOqbZZ9KtsUeXEdJzbHtiWfveVfh59l237B0psllWbsaWABiesawlCllFoIg7IHpQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQ4pnTUZtwwkiup7ueKbVZ2emN2DewHTDdBTbHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU1IZPd8KADa6rITY3ZmO1C1PkzbGs4godExeyYmCfAAgHglvIHB4Yz0GVSm5UEjYDpzAY2hEUBLCjGIf99oT/rMnnjjiccAt67p6u0hAG3PWNfo6ZOhl2ZtCANikv/ZwLD8RgvgZABxZHOsXk0INWPetvVul2WgvQIeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPbAeoBrECjHxg1H55GY0p1A1Uec@usHwmA@G7oQ9iqw9d20dmETUMtKBPUp0h3KeO3Xf0EVCjaxBNP9t7ytyO7cAb/DAu7zc3genoHtvcZPHdJ/fjrB5Wi@y0hbCKauwcqiAWBLJTfTiBFhKtCRvqxwlTC1hl8bV4hcWBLFqG5XIsB92zxLQ8EEnNlMEB/VzLqvArMK3Ecir0lHw8jfn0HL1vDg0OpY9QitjAtTzT4J7Jsaxa4jH79rDHo3UosyLLllihyIp5VoR7mZU1yA1B55hazsOvAD@AVgZUVPhlcxzQvN1DO8W2tsN6@sgcznzoBL7D8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW4hWF7Q2A2gP9FMBLQ/MEuY4RMh6sQgUeysaGQpwPWSvP3h1g9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaSeOFcAfGcOgnGbiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdPcEMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPH44HetvwzA5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZ7CnCpQCdlg/FUZYHnOE5dndkYMikgUHZxH7n7TBhBSwmCRxxkVsC@xpCe4QhoqMjK8OObRBjCuCYnswgExg3DfsUx3niLgvZuMSB2g4O6zBcdA3HYRgXZAE3TbzKnbRd4/UEB6Q5Xj1gfgbwyJ5uDkMEqEPqHnFSeMZdyG@2iHbPsUfUa0fIi4a2PV7B94HznSGgh/aZMUd9zhj18XgIww/4G3z0A2TOdBJQSJqJ5soRgkSYrjMwASBlBWzbdIwO0d4vOqTOAoNfRLHCtPqdLEK5FxmXsmxsA892MY01GQ4rMGAYHZatK13jVEEfPnYtjlmIQzCawZjkg2jrIFwg5oRFCOmOJtM4eRTUrGuPFovGGdVeWPSBiSPM8EyfQe31gEcZU30EIhBDOcOCUXEELYbXINYECHlYrD3Wta24F0I5c0AagEKHJSGJA2nimSMDxEUbkmCN5whpZJOEWXsGTZmolZNJPuSYXCGULFwlFPfIRTx4Z4FxszvpINUwb9OiFgTjjYvCkmPoXe4neA47Ptbh58DAOPZFYhkdGPEQUYtIbjCqGkB9X4TpEEQc7A3LBTnMlZmJAiu0/L7dg8Z2ZkLZQUSCpHPYHSICkiD0msodWSCSYwManQyZyTrjMQN/EDygeT7IlGAst1@Z7A0EDgcgi3UmjjNj0zHUhDmCWF7H7vWg9b4xxgMAwUZd1pl1oHtCJWPrEbo2caLOeLGY87d1A@JYKN3tPP0a6xtAdhj5eyjOY5OfF2A8piIQKXSLSwWWDpTCInTGMyILgAlT9GxbRv@ubbjUWGznJOz6mJlr9KlrQD/rzZnRCKUcaKUWSWdd4Dx@90L4mKGwtDCYld8KPjEs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE63WQ@0kogsgAKb3ukYY89vJzaxM9OKCE77D1BwIl/JBya7A2H9Ltu80mogathyIkIBCpKI@tiX53Tktb7qA2KCZcxld85ZhrNr2UOM0yu5iy8xzgIGL8UVOIypS6AUSUxi4iErQe5odgbICz3kNiS4QG9zJteLD37R7J0Rk3ph3oiNCmxHkJXQC/FYDUOC3/A6IHk8RFj1BQ@MuuBxC2jdHS2BbIdIDrtRX1nRZWCKtwEd2Za9BCoQM4SLURZDqC6oMR4i19CHYWOk7uIu1BEy7Lk2jgMZjKHjse1Az@BMZ0YqGVVZpHX5mkwiHCuSoMkvDq0wZMRxwPdwFIQE4yHob9TFsKeCiKoDpwAmxjUN4Hk2zzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEsty0ApV3dmHAgUD4ZnyGjGTMcBNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6FzIWZEc1O@vZi5ji96ZtM3pVXWmg57yK1c41R3WQ03GAaEDOlEi3nPjySr5U8pIkKjYY0@hpPwuQkSKJEOVJ3qgHMEg8QAYzeHM6iTEhS4mppk48XolMQkOTMhlNPYVfexdxe4V@GGjGZ1Av6a3KuvD8C1JcJfQjzDBAEXGAN0BOQM6IYjs5XK3rbML4B6glk93KDUKl/RU5VyYl2F1w7x8QiAu0fLKPAvX6ZBDioxqWAKMTiWnQWKBgO9JCUoogoei@GMrepC0x8NIruGeE4smLliCiyJJdh4K@TAAJAgZE4QPs2N6LV9cuXMnEFzWajVobCBNAdvsJqPqQTDDIwOnhsgySSN@JrJnH3rYNxJJKC9GvuTYgNgELbVWZ@fewIEeR@@XAkQCsgoWtuSAsH49PzFPJt2rFW2hJ0YSsdeB0GR2PLEqwODPe0PtJqrGF6gKKkQcqYqNF9MT6GuNl3yxQkU/mmO4KP7WfFQiNZxADPy2upREPKnvN2/QO7PO0BcJuAs6O@dGbUD/xJ8RCBlR2pcJgk57radyINgdOBz2dPvoYc3vizxQaZtWZcFjaHf0IXmvY3QxSPto797B9sHXWktgDM125aqHYuZKBRxqJ1Opb02UnKxV1qMw5oDvt26GjQkX44iCH8wkexoRlWYdGFymATn3Dz69ShKQhJAclAO48XdFpOFxQOgS2ro7uDIIs34qBVmGSYK4TNpjAczQgahjuB7g83Ty5g1W3lWkxr4/Yjac6BxA4KnsWUE6GQOvCGBBULvHR0RKC1KoaeHM7NwVjRng8wlKzVeRIVE60mQ@2X@we1AjsP4khURRFNcDWUp3ujK0@eGkawjL4gD7A1eHpeQ54ihPE65LCdzpLBB4XrdsBXwAgLqObDNpOAqK5g4A952rZSNfqRO2AHonCFflyqg81PlQRCN44BDXQZV32ShKAfPBKvRaOmKFoYvDViefN4q5cnTY6szz7EaB0uwqjAOB3OhA0IkroY88lyJ9sdpH//DRNcRdEiJBFZACzNwhkykvdyig9iKZLO4qO6Ch2UNDfk4cT2RiUlHiwQSr3HFJ@YzE352aXiKT5E81CXEh9@3tPe1@ENmf@6OZDFIaUBfHkcnp4YJIx4U2YtlDu2@zDUjDpcMgQxCbVhZzu29b12pIR08sagzXVID/4sSNPoaxxnxDiiOliqqrfHVGt9wz4NJqIYtEIgoRKIXiy6/0Ux3INS/34d4XuzCIqPlMJnRn6AISRNIQudDVifiSB5MgI9nHZ2kBw/WVa709CJAiCxxYaJ/RhQm358FLPYljysrS@EtR@op9jeKv7NmVpgU@vGmBI0KyvSdPH@092X28/fmxp@XzC@@5TLkAhIP82iALyQNON@ytG7xrYrEQXAz6hoPdC7jABBSUYNp94jrAuGWMInMEVrQavjKV@Io9sOJu8mphzjBUemV1eBN6jJ2PR/UTgqLdHaIy4vDlPRzPsf0MPG/sVhQFevlg0pZBaVVedeyh3lcoHQwMw6Giouqyt4/zGu6yFICMOzN4Cj65BaLDjGYQ9eHIBuWFFgmRNbAEB0@zVkOzPwBdGFcSDScphy2YSqN0QUMAXVkJy0YMmN6Atv4zqCeRN@2PVK3E27Wa0XKKGERb6P4Qd61ngOqUgNEKSJG88sqO7xzfYTPg0gjpKpAYkzdoksNlOBYMGQiSNGuKen5AHOIWOF@KvIJo9HqCs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpXmcgebYE8CS7R/MGkVbYczu61ZM3fEeALMh9H0NRs40Xx8dWEwT04zuEGy7gNWbNhtpMVtn1JBt@/GQVWu9C8bDtBh7QdskJTZOebAU/6@rX2VlXp97VZYo3GvtjjjRmj7dBkHpjA7/uGtG@hwmUaKCysRBXwchvlSUTQkNMKuANKaVAh4KRFpqegnhJIPSieAgtB/hWJAGbz2bwcvAF8QgfQaUb271px12a8Ue5BmdL3TEQkSabO8ilXZwf9GB0DFs@cmmoXGTS7MyI4zy67vLZSkjkL5YG6UFXCyHQrHw4I22Fy8DQCCgVqefAOaBd4bTpYD7LiEo/tDTIkHDCyQeQICxaPegDn4HEvCDbvCA8J/JZLNKJZZ9ZCK1tsJLUNj0@2W9PHFw0NLvRskH0rMbjADQqXISv0@pi2@jwWVaemEoBSqDORsbIxqkEkK6IFRhUBJ2vTKIu6OKMNXSrjITLLwBfYnd3gIt1DD5fJI1QiYImtcvinqNsS18ouvQGWvMNshUWfju6tE6VfhQQYHGdmGZJ/BlQkk7sEUV6TvMtGHgvEHeF8cwbQImhhYl6zR4b1lWdj2uEiWSV1nPjcWD4ppU4j6@trcUr8Xo8Da4tcG2iawtdKXBtkUsiF8aT0UUp0uTC0AalQL9m/LIRQJ4mm9gGpig5vDHHCb1RqWSbab2h@k8Nn0moCqA8xJbwAXDiyVoNncmkWD/DNRuQ3yNl38G2c9hxzLFPgq@AQMDffRpkiQig3qM07xhV1E1vpsio5oDSaKCImXDix43McfP4/LibOr6MpzF1sqrXQD8E5uUlRnLfsSdjENwauYoEvC3ZyFaa1XYtnolvJBIlaQgZ6cnkx6VkSue0TsQNaFOJ4@M4kNSnTqMzcAjeNK0lkyGhAI@eCVrGcJiIy@clyL@dbCZTcUibjKeBLdficaBLB4ngUqFxRoA3ogfmFEgJHROGuOiaAjFIWpzC7vqFMR7MnGiEcNYNpGycQZ8v@uPeCOTiUS75hqePCnQLmn4g9/J4INzi5B3KS@MZ5@4Cx/RYWdiyEoy7p1JvZHu68pkMSpMcGS7ja3FFkmAkpBAOiYr92HSxC@uWYU/c6Ezj0glQzB18jwYTYJbBfp40tCpzLBidgc3i63cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQC6HRl@yERRKsHFEpAuaGeGCXyR9rTQrIxKSHDWE8zN5wvj13KYW5XSsAxmZPYt2zEkIAmkEGgbCm1iEurM3wmzRzNf19Yl/FAa0lDxNg3giA@Gtk605ew6sh40HkXSg34OSQ6MrjAE/tED9ijzunCMrrIh0Cqt7QxghIDSICfWwtoa@QGK7Y67sjeFpEICB9xoINfuQOg8Y11N0wqdfK8ShGGrAGIPoJJQK7VAxQ2CJBUCk34l7/JpoUBHf7J/f5fPndBgi8MrzqO1RnZ3AnKlrzcdGFY/zXahPZmWPTKBDEH6NyfDA9v2uJYPL6tmZrjSbI4mQ53mfK5Oy9yYrmO37SFNBd2UdB5/4rj6UOeTUEHo9mePQdZ/dnRYkyuRSIp@Oroxb5yHXJ4tp@dedM2R1luD5SGXN0xxPS/iuBVsk0M24wcUMGDib5KDOgr8i@gfdClcQ/H9S@g/wg1yICv7swj0Gnr6EcsUETfN4c4h3/NczVyi/0odLIynUjwuOM6xPVc18j/1er0F7yx5n0jImoZz7xx5881zCzpiFKU8j4Q76RbiRAEVKE64oe5qPJ95hXsNBsYwWEE8AMEEV8lgbB@i@AS6CUrifM@bAYL0GBdDiEPjEhvrgKzpXpu2gD41lnhsIbZG/QTGMAUlF2FdYf4Ud5V6imX7S5Mu5542qPY0e7JZ54vZqDo5XGtT@OT7egtAbNarwQalVdEwp3g8jEZQCTdIQcWk9ftrRQ13Y7g0py5QkqrgKqA1TLWMdDwt7jYv4opLZOgx8fh4@nFG@xzUD9xdtn5H6RtVzHAVvapBSNwXVdszJoFgh7H4/HRnAOyEpaaLpIT6mVg9e9iV@GIYtAvG1SisIH8vQrjrzd/caJhOsOGNdhzypMhGI3vlrsG9UqX16xEiu@tCQNBLztnFSfr0gjVgZDuV3fHQ9JrsUvbs1gBJ4k0c6@o@PC5qOo4@cwV/K0uNbR988lkj0@QQhJGOC1wlXovTYDsnyMcgD@H@WnDhhhzP9GjApw0HJpZXlQGpKa2FAPoAg2dQZWFGfokQ9QvjYl6WngEKacJAzN3ZKM2M5KXcG@qeZ1i8zfFVxtXk5stBfjY1yn7LX1uosAwtwIAAamIYoFhlh0f3dw8OZGi5biK@iws1FeiOemcAcsiqQgeUjBa@wj7uxtnHmCaJ2rkAXQ2UjJafHhp1FRo9qBmQO7KIvuEkwDOJaywd8KZlLUrIBTGfQLitquMRjUJgCSMJZSJglaX4P7O4RuXjWYEWnyJKArkTdypAWzMpTyzztezCeELiKUSJc50UhoXaeoKY2rqapNbjmCNcIQZFimRDKEGjwaQ3wPQgssiazSpf6oe4qGc5faSuKFJV0K7fmhpUfQ28QXIhCH7y2lv2opGRys3U@jJQtIfM37DLyx@BixAWQbvG0mzXE9Tfr3VkjgNf8uOM/BlpzVd2pVfYOneIfGqZogf7oojp0Daqxe1Qi5utoJMhK6EZFyxIwBJi/nZqv81SOHF@UG0wGXkkkuw8JLqGJGcXF0RDtq4xoiG4VMYr4zJQMoExPbKhNI/8rdRRIYB6q79fBPvssSAG2tTigiyGcEldOb0ihEqnYjQdFwJN68SmZZ3Q1crIah4FvzD16GR4PWXPdAd0W4ga4sDjaquwc0ftHt2WRKDVDX/dnDxo3twXeUFW1JUDetAU@pKcF/eKLGTbNnoTq0@LjOhm0utbYkrlEkXutdvmqqhABNz@FTyXRAMmhe1Zk3OyGuzNxhkXGI@AcXElZV70q9uM2ALdYXTwIJX//K9f7wL9r9fOAAYKnGAMHS0YurGmpN7KyvKT4gvdllcsnwefDE2dCEOu20B2dAeKpA9Dx3LQtNYuSTD8j3DlwK9xaJt4A@HwhmbGMecLf8FzeSbL1s4sYJmdVXGvbLviWdEqD@hvXSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYEz5SktEk0Y2djtSwd4oRo2Z1/tg4k34HeTTWyvRHOPvpr7px8zk9bZqgIaot03jhip39JNJ15bGJ/1QTi0siTsvPS31SiAO@Ku@LXQuLz4voGP2YZwNnquizYc25Ywet7UK15q4Y6lNynaXv1FHGN2QgzPk91VRTP9QU@hYTTVzSLf3bIk@dGgo/qYHBbeUShGimVfIPNTbM5RBBh/eysINBMBxap1UKpNdsYI8Hq9OjwojpS@Xl6eeyh1Oj2VTAQrftirxyTIqsL@R9ZZaheHKHOlDSetGnCuZ@bL9B9eihkuXlMY4xYWb06U1N6c@DkidyVB35q4bmvgcj2C1YNXEsz9sPDU7NogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gBN88Idw3TLbLLwVxGxi6ohTiIS6FrOQuwOx7uDF3Rpt6DofEdmbjvNdJIZHsVpTr2Gf5Wig8DUE35ffmI9mYpVu/BnKRhZ6jDOL5yOFiYA8Q5xlsa6pnpGnRbTtiTpYh6neFS/8UuEMzuRWfrbmvWrjm0XXZI95sI1HeACvy@vEFHaWnqlkRz3lH3DTwo2Mowr1B92LeHhVJf0eG2stYnTg/5vv98Xw4XcihVvYVDBeKPban@cyVfP1Gck9sqiA54ObiNNeK8YYhdxqb8JZbVpQPFANfnlpfsQaZEKWWFz@ityBhXVs70WfD8OYaOVaQNho7xjMRpkO4wQbkEDs/hIvbPk1vu5ty678eUroEt3laISOWeDA0YrOh@rUqZllE/MIWaybw/i@oNJ8bEWKpo7LdfGXjc@AYl4/2RyvjFWPcn5HENAE@ghLHe@Jrhe2GN4zS@3chM9KHZMW4XZRaZ2hik7zGqzk/B8RQd11P0rcl4oVYXtDPr4GaSDcZBl7a7C9hhyIfyodItktKCfO4a9LtRY@IaHu4Dq@UymYwvwEQWVhZebtKksmHaVya/L2RMPvOc53FxMc2JOJfnQWSJ7jRcyYK0VYo9RS6XFcu0DG@G9/fkpm3bHn5ITQFT7ZooioFkSTtqb6qxa@KOf1aEzacuXJzwaPdWTVrw0cbXLYE@qDTfVOnRlZ/3qk0J1zZHuO60@Hrz9E1kHem2XPCcNs4J8T22w9WypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqt02hjp/TAu5m@CV5eyN8BaZhr8mi2u4fOV2vuIeu8KUxjMgltkFLWVgjAx6vUHK17toUsB/rIw0tfG3KnhqGB1lumt0VkUYm8AXLLwvLBVHhCXPtkC/8nA7H@opQ9ww6vuu4sDB4t5SIu@N9L7BbVncxCnnExa4aYardXPn8qmLCt8o04Fkc@MFq5sEdKoTY@YGz6UAH886UK@T0e3TbVc6fwfnQN@jt6/aqXp9iLUG9sAaGAO@PTx8W9U5oD163PbITagD1v0B7lgbjxd2skfpObSHw/ehJ7JGzihtu7cUp10844oHtD4I7kxvQ4D/uHXyTvc470DHyl4zMCYwLrm2Z48Nid5WRR3iRA@/r@KhwVr0zzuDdKOeDxQJnj8v/Ft1y75ue@MxPVrj4cSlGyWV6GjybXJTj@9Aob2PttOX39ijtux7yv72FFoCX85i2qbXGeDZcN6yjb7d7gzM25BuG7pnmSdKMOXDX99Ld0XKmEy6j97y0ATyOjMZ20stGn6Ij71Vle7PHvFhLXTcIK8sm6Gj09fSWD/puHw2FF2sghPCkd7Iz2hX6JR75fXE9OZAI1uWwuldviyBjlW4@5skVkpWdBRizob9zRMrWykJ6SiQS0YGBB51VbaL29kiXSyb5bdVCEVLSRhFtp98CLn9LT40O2hG5m3Bf6F9LexNWjrIWYNJ373OMPl0fRdENLytnragLcuRKWsYs3TLf6wiszZU8CwjPFsgc02MG9dU8jcuqlA8dSjptgmPFjyg6iYr59CG5tjldyb1Vi7F@VuWQBe/ul7IaTNbrkz7FdM1enwJBF23iYgj28ENxyCDSB1cSccZdGTmXPDijMuy@8DUpSGbRw7irhJblu4GWl794Zgpff7E6Ou4pfqR6eGezCWtgprssl1Et8L@6kR3za9OoGSrGhsaZuDLkE70BD@@LYH3WO@bnYcLFREi6RPY39DJHwvNH72u18XZwHRxR1PouGFiCpscb8TY6lqgNyyJeXXePrRJMe9A/LTj0tjL5tbt8QwPhc3IddO0uunRLKv/XKU6rtrrdSMSZ5PReOL6j@U40J6p6Cz06IT83TMTgEuvgbWygT70ls9UR6ZcQQrzB8W5c5U0/oU5tPvsi1KGgdAGQhgK50sazj0Ynp/ihhzHWtISKe/3XPbEiQ7J4QV7DXVrZJlkWqZ382yO5@HmnOCJheEjBx5EUB7hXb77oRCko@UUeXS7rD8/gXzL@A4t79CeOB0DnaFZkaha4Odq7ASbjPHgho1mUc6iWlrHHkL3AsdwaZfp2NbEk5yJdeOoULhxVKiwaakQaQYs8dXdx8@S0dZAm7Jvk0INUP4m7nA2d63cMHClkZkWCGKr@ehi7ECXuM/NIR3QjuBb0myjzaYOsev79jJ95@kMBpD3VpiA@U9G940OLhvemvcT@7Ft2TAajYFRjg4MfrR/YaPH8oSY7BEeXgf6dG/N5pDArhiEuLShj4021O9w7nqfsYgDvq97@oqhiOYGSf8LXbe2FXPYNpxXNOkXca9SaRcRemhMSbdY3WB4H5S8ToeLxDgft9BHFlZs3LFtW/xO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vf9CuYz77RfmBZbqZ4tF3T/lu0SMLrc9saqsjtG2h/x@w54ky@R7AnTHNFzlEZoyIL9Cjkkgfbk38pDijTxkrhqBJHuqu7RIv1zVmINUpx@wBWigOx0bV8J8xw27cyL2B25h0@EWfr5xoA2EnwLH0jsT37jibWgNR@0R3VYqDJHaPDDaePinTUY7PH16vTL5zJBvsSCyoys85x@wK@zUBZZ4CtpI8vZha0GPWqSqOaYbceqVy@W0WUeyTKPzRsdZM5voNZ@bXgiHMitPyLlirjrSjWgWWdHpQPvSnrS4dQ0EmqEheQMHdH7Fu2l6O7CmsmQ9ZDIycJF5cRVmpehquwMqrL18PT1kro4h@Sb9gJeE5v24fChtr5Q8ETz879/7igKDcKuQCyyMAOu6fQUfkJ84lv94nxb41Ha9njndB7zxFMAqdoLFykMSePCega6NVYWA2rMmQz770I/suxp1SR2TyGqtJA2JXXuGZFinEtl7m14vkc3PdinbaO3UM7qSb@4AVxqkR8ExrzCa/1yygBrljbjZU1U4YaeFnL/9cxlxzwLOAPKW7Uljl57K2H2692j/SB676tLxaXuApyOuyXEL9hO0UiYyJfVKdyLrnXw7Wtd0PeXeoSrtPNqTMcIKevMVDQkeuDK38Fg57@mbE9UVfaUWhKGGt1xAfHj0@FFqfhKTJXYGjj0yktHgncPDNJ40@crh0uBo6gfQO3r2dGXyvV1VTS5pvs8sWh1cxT2X5LQK0pEB2ig0xofc/MqtwlXHHhvdo9nY@AwGT@Tg7ntmX1hZyCf6qdnHXsjKKwlFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcq24YTPVfV5Yo6RW3boofDHyu0oKDlkFSe7XHq4acX/qhTDMv5OhA9LpGaut1bPlKBn9AfoUnT374uYqqqr6Hyo96BeWX5lZS1GWLY@PLRP32Mp2fCVFyn0kjxoVZJ56z7yojQC1q3gDafnfU9wtldug7kJQOhdWNrhzwxrplsSrWXdJF5UIDVuarsxyhfGeyxIhTt8TtHA89I1vnBLPUt0yJm8JeMjJ5JkZ@fe3m0JDnxa3hzrkyfP2FPdRVsjN0eMYmy8B8ZzyeiVhPNWaOhu5XJq1wFQ2o3w@uPl/bnCDnWna1uz6e2LcHTUFId2siEcwsI3imQMzam5bKzq8Hmtp8u3Gd2WNz/EYc8W5OCoDRof0Ltv/QtVzWTIwhA@1Qx/vaVmgg7OEujSZ2i2Lhp0tBeyhg7KLTJ4JJdqo4@MKW5H4bPBy5T6peNb4Yaxr5hcPZzcFFa6ISx3Q37XwtCTZeWMegPA/A1hLC@HwY/s4dnAlnd0x3CX7D9eitBNBSnfUJByhDu/KWVwEpQWFn33ahEfjy74j6Wt9cjwnNx4YLfN3NIybPfQliR7jDbRr4f72yl0h7a39G3/yAd/X57f2cRYmtFj/c3yAOI0J0uDgAkagwkdibgevLhA2gaZ17D6JjejyO7Z3i69LUXyqY071pdmed8c35@MVyMKLBGt91/l4gsRn4OqbJ@57B6eiJtL50tUftwWt9x/lSjLwvlANCL68Gg7aFT7h4oWyXGOxedPF7zxzKi3fxjxc4zpdJWuK01XqY5LQ@a5PjnKLWS7WX9xuoRYq48ZgZQBbDh8rhR/OI/7yuF1ToBa28AbDSmEHzQ8mFhRW9Ru2rcmwg/m8uOQrhwYDE8krFQqmVz8zEX0bCdabE2so8XCdTrHCXEvLtiaf3YSAsTgNKZ/WhQNm4EuZ@BxT4FAeLV1yKZWU/NltoXflqiApJakHNGLzEcFeTXY@rl/ELJSUS/ZWo2JFZH5R1FDa7DcoinARVuMUCYmnahs3YOQ9eAYJSPj/OyCkfYH4qaaz8CbrEQPlFf9g6aA0vr5072nu4dH20fPDhuZ5qV/EDUohGVBbsFx94@zXRHK7pMNRhVu35gOQA8hO/pwAGqNblAuBiW7UrTaQtHmhRK3MM36uWUpCp3FVaRLwE8SeW4UCiIienHYQYmpfvxj2BV@LJZO90IVcdAi5Ql1VmGZZRmPdeCQ65YffvUjKBSKH8mp4GdyMGPfJC00@b5td/0cXYPdfgU5Ptjee/TsYJcFCM4bzZnZ9Qa1cp5bLOb2AaCeeiZtTqqxuJ8kDnVVq8UfxIEwcTnOKnR6mqwFQzuHaAF18Ny1n3qDJdYJPlAwHlaK8l@/rlzGZdxnm4S48QCpOGQLTZ4aytraGjuCRsLuH@x9tnvAEP/d@@SNJEIQ7AiPbv7Zj7vc3n5gQSX4QJAzIr5GliqE6PHt4Ezz/Ng10py67nj1Z4LIvj0dbg4N64dfBhEE@u4CtNszMn52xTBWkmzV8M8a@XbLgoyoCQU2unFKF22QOS47NV0Tj1YjDj00CbbY2HEXCJnBk9k2fgMJv7Sk08cfAPWJ5XGzO76Rjhi0NDlkOWm2TsjyT0WIkYjxzTVo7G0DRjrmWqAnG16FvYKWiNOmFX70XpLq8WtJAtAVcknIJiMRr9kQc5VjR3n3a/9M6VcZuD1wf9t3TzP34O1X/LceuH@Vu18o2NCu2xyb4xJFCO0E@iXgiIT0R9pHPv1kcXMHc8KhabSArzJzBNV0SlTH6DwHfpeAHc/hJBqfQaVBc4Ma880c8PwMp5lAQ4UVRcEmhdKXTJvMjSnf8XXFYGEhX8ipCiApnQYAycJ4H4@ycoDJZAW6iXBqjmsvYWjf3NxkIqpgRq1Q5TWrrFsvsuLLENF1iCucDRC5BoM0kGSeAsLqfjIYfFJqEpMi94qrcWRcXRtGJQrH0QvfLZ8QIksAsTiNDDRZPcWvhHnOLDC82cbvakW@PrHuA5JUGJPIlRQF30DAE9uD5gOddP59GW4gAHc88hEQLdq5/Bt5ZO8S26N8vWfNz7UGn7nw@5qMPICDymauDqbRuhWfI4hDBFERlzXfxgt27B1bTYW3TQbN9AdLGrMF7l9W@ivaLC/39nVrh4mrtgqRWOzuoWWjrvkACsMSmqJlFbWQnBcpl1taJL9EfjZQHLS1cgHZAZsCltExzFf22N3e2d37yv7Tw2sW/Shm/Go04Pv1zdSxJKcbzdARjxZrsUruPVAOH997EFTEHOlChBsD4/dLot5UkvkUEoKcH0m4WrRlGF4t3WqMn/NDy1fxzWo3oUaJruGhZj4gX9oWLD2gwz1XM9dKy6iVz9@E0hyeEgG9w09mXkM1kTy/bDQ368dWLH69JSzpCC9i8gZ2AnAduxvrCjb264XDgoVfrzzCz1y50b6YXd4XxfUsGpbCg@GefTI3qeV7RAIi5Q2yARYpyEoQdWXv2@cy@tzwm8a/rslNUEUN7EQQLmRuongE1FHwoU7kInOzlb7FxgEoK0OzLQSGjbjlxsDAXGi0kRslSiQF/@MHPOOE/@nOaWUq0x6gRBK5HcFKs5uMQAbwkgJ0aJTunk5ASXpqj7kxbFrrvW8ErgMb2C@osKQkGuwrkxHE69HjwKB5d@DcEiQGSsZDVLksBVzCtwE5TaGVTcivgZYg/YLLo24@MU3KA2PaNfvA2xPJNHC0j1W1yUI7kVhosgtpxUWqs3kt3NgVP8HztlGyf5Cx0OkcAb2hy6CEGtNE/CyerDQhf/SPnz0/jSfFZW2JjJb6Vjy7V62XhugX1Zs5ie75vTMwDbqMW5TL17kE@F0FzM1rBV/iKZflgSvQl9VqKLkfes4jcIIYkeiN9DFLTCxumkxm9Jo4Tlhpstkk1bl1Q4ulUqRQwYMCZEYpe@Ti43dCt2YsodSgEaCva3Xx8cYcs4Yqy01wUyZJto5fyNoBiQtt8iUF0IEhSYXA1rAJgZoBGPFOIvMGDmkwHOLCgwy8LQmmDwbR9KSNNKFSs/odFvni2aLkKJbLFb9CF7limUHru84OZQXAXuNzgVwP1PWtlgDNQP2VhdickV/neDHKN8YReeibOwF0YhGLpIEVFAaw5vZCOwMHf4ldC/oKyAeVyrOjB61SUhFZaDal75hdnD7nRrVDFc//DAp0U2UharzKNbpPMBkaqGtxuyxoJ@0BdRjxCkuNRclw9YPE87apqje2ej@hXwsQM4cDgH@8rBWAQ0uMwUaGJWHLmf3PfoafPBYT66p60nJOU/F8pgo3tZpnefbx@rEkrTcytbvrOmhR3uvpMejkykbu/qkx6LX3@sqxKLIsyynKxvl5/MHGU/OFVng9vcyqpdcnY7XQkF9Pm2Kplj5psqdPP3/bepsUp6ez1@JxQqNP8u7sX4hqDhX9WKXMzrcK2dhJGb9uyXQ9f8KmoLeyE/YGrpMew39yv@lG3Dq627039HWguMhix8f4KWOxKCpKI96Ef1L3X8LFFf9GXa7LW823b5MNXfemM2aa5tjtduFnD0CC1JKHDPK9A5ye4ivsmJ6kQNE1mvbm8wh6Hm51Dc8ayndb6EO2DqfbRr8/2dVn5uSB9/iL58H1DK83B0smJJqpVEKSGle9Ky09H2NaRvuzn6xdps@ftjb/7BsjxVjDxz4@vn35GN2Hav7jtbWP793L5dKapnH30y@efm17ezt3P51/2shv5aTM2uaf/snamqZtaspa03XVZrxxcvK5qGVyovxnP4q3nj79quvWs//H19/WVbwV4XbKisAn4MoyFZx4L8FPRRnrfa/Ymxi0cjU2o79WLPA/X2Nqfav43767/zrmxeqa8tyBpxd7HSuUYtwJDnjLBm@nsXpsE6MVLmMzpVargbP43/49pK9/BeBgyGwTbvV8AKswi9WlGiW5iNUL4FA1DfL9v77@9QiGnE3USIwLrrusAZeYK2riVhOuDbo2BTRHJ2UUJYhneQPPsJlauqPewRcTXuBhGWi@2/COY/itWLZ/l7GDRiqVasotCS75Bc4RKaqqHavqHeAG0scbtZq0wbi9vWw2fwdNAydpRqtvw4Bp3GHP/zGu2DLP6gcCORBihbW7L@/X61CUbD27UU/R5fcf6krFkmjbd0WWZi/joHg0mi8f8f7C6mKmpInpdJp3oikSSJrO2w99Uz7Gr9AHOyq76reQBKL4vrEPjxfbxevP/9c//96ff5f@vke//4RW@qyu2VM2INIpdIQ6XHcrlU69LtYd8fwY3@vQejKVUqWktC6PExvAd5oHTM18chHPZ@OHjDqQythxklLDRdnW/ezxvR6be9e5Tz3q5wfwyOTB/FKQY4Fq5A6pdi0eDKj@fkapcVpvSigG1aSGWsg3JZ4qwLJeZo27UE2iViyLzbqW1/ah6lSRV9xg3WV2DPTBQkBHH9/6vGz1MGT@Vo96xepBsvo8zofGC9CtC7FGQ2kaNAwEfuzuWmWtVClUNKUVel6/WPW6l2EYT93YaSy8OHVic4LGwqZ51S@oivCFBS2YfUg8ISYZ7B/4AuhbcK3BH/3DFb7ifY18fG@Kcv1aYxV1Q8sq@Y8Lu9oH5i/A8MA67Xb7TaeNo7/e1ju66ukTfarPdK89aU/bXmeCJnbev0xC7G1jjR1wNtRkqeA6Tt16PZPllu8kh40/SbKnMSH2j3DVVU1lGzAsZeAGshg5QVXGP1UVWOwcrubbjcbbDeih9dQmscdmXfKxhIfcuttMSZeXDXBXq/7/Zj10VuniLihc8zKV2nxRB4njRb2RApAvfJAyhym36s1NCgjz8jPzgzebILJIqc3GZs3eoR8kgUtqAsDNBSTjOTtesO/eTcnwfhfS19ebLJlKrUvSGo6HDX@kgBTNeiooEmKQAAnh/Pzn/IFyBx32cvOyftnYvLzc3IT/Tbpf@k/wvdy89k@P@bUizjy8yRpZrdRE9nLcUOrHyrHPLJrwLit19JGVY3DU4QnxQKYQYhtsI4Z217KxDSH28t2X/zP@jt99@fsoaTH4MypC7Bx7hrKBelqZq2twY9Zjiz3mlwVu/AWv6IMej@voafGbhUs5ivJSZhU@W55QS4WkjINYy@618Ci3zF5CVBR5gLczUSsVxFZKnWkstikWisTdf/HaFY/H/8lLrVyM84kNPIH80nXdxxHcQuzYY4hd1TKqpF7UuZVt/t2DX1x2/ZNfXHUJsYsyMypAlo7LOEGEGNRCTJKA1dc3R7hFFZcWJNTiTmufS8@2JZx20D1aOOpwlbq2t1srl@t8VWT9KbW4jfsbcFfhf3cNiiHE2q/x79Eb/GNHHfw7eI1/7OgN/h14@Mcet/Hv6DX@bbfx72iEf/de499jD/@e9fHv@BeyWbUqrp8TAVJqWb1cn4pEiGpsq378C7x2evGffucb34jXanEpTh9cyKm2w9RkFUjouvHq3bgQq7F1dV3NDDOdjNpW2@AwWcZhmUFmoHZBsmipLGOwzCwzY5mRrXbBZcBfBlxmpscyfZaxMhZEhFBwea2Mh64ePPrw1wNADvyZuG2qrWY6DDIaoghPX2pD8OC6aB0LDRZn4ksD9CtZlTNywWzi9y0a4suXx8pGUyuXmIwNQ241Xh7Hm2gJWSvnWHtmrB2/ZDEXFLRqTDk@VvhUE5SVyHF52WrtPrnfainIb48f2/vz//39UfT1xv/Rvv143x7Z8L@/vw8N3Kin7qaku3DVgEP5j61Yvbp1XCEGFzC5mLK5dVzPSugupIBxaeiX@sBrDhGe9bVjIX6WQNn6DMXr6vOz6mmV3GfBKzha1XmEIBp3@E@4zoCXB4L3GVynZ@igN3SePT8OXdyhPD8Dr@cMFIvwHxSY6Os/wL/5/67/x89YkiUazWTi/HIzQVcS/5LJ88vzS/9eTyYS/ktiE/7QA94xyfllHZ0U6RxcjUSymby85H5wTyQ3OcA6ZLNZp7TzeMC8Y2GWlC2/Jf5hn5C1fx3Hq0yfbxI5Pp5mMslqOzDgjkue@gWtxCer9JGu9XZDbf7pj8hI/1aSIuVz1aq6wfiLltOq1VzwVixVq6XgZT2RKF@/6pkttQBidS6XTFar8LIVgM3Aawi2BGCDlzxANVy943PB8719Ml8PXCIfw@9GcLaQyNDHL/A7SnGxIt65k/C/z7y1nbxzRytnLi5Cn/EYvNQFr1arazqtFvpnLy7Elkh7Nsp5eM@ULi7UTDmlxpO2k3iCH@CCrBKSyj7W6pRrGZivlism/2EkbQCW39ws5Or1Qg7chRKuHl@/iBpMXI/HzoMhu5jkrDG@rohVrrhB73bxYueXMap2lssnE8BckyACXcbwj3ur5TL3T7JcIVFKlf2/2hronyCK8D@c7cimchvFjbsg3eHfdOmFPLl6btTUy9q5UcFZ48tqx//8KR4bN@7cyZaBrKVM9Vhote5vH223WjVRFFGcgRt6EncX8KtrYyfeoCrPl5sNLGHzOB6vVO9S81BLeQbtwI8nxWGYYKUyEUIwe2gTAkovcK1gja0JGj3xJpQ5JdfAE6R2zBp/XbhYl7VZHy/Wx/k/ZrIhXWzIeDjdO50wks0vPzR8pbR4hT5GeAmxp4@2d3aP0tqmxGLag@2dtHb47F5Mxdf8/J2Cs/h@sLt9f/8ZJHj6aHf7cPeTvc92nz0Ff5edza@Az/v3@TPqWvJ@xp4Lr5w3umHoxsQwWmeTydlr9so0WybU33AChbD7DnONFuA@1uflqMKvY7r6q1e6M6aLvfvBt9794L9798PvvPvht9798Hs//fJ734Lfj@H3Hf78zr8r5/H@0y//xe@@@50fgud/gt8fwe8nP/3yN7/Of/T@x/D7LxG/P/Z/kXj8JwCsX/npl9/90U@//NXvw@9f@b/vX//92k@W/773zdU/TPfd3705znf@Pfx@j8MK4n7nd7gfPq/F/x0e71e//@43/gP//1P/D50/fPcbf4w3/@Wff/9P/8u7b/xHTSv96b99983vvvvmN95989vvvvlPtXe/@W/VTPT2u@@@9wd/9Ye/91d/@D/S/4/p/nvv8//u@//8L/6Xv/jf/uIP/d9P4PcfwPWTv/iP0Df@9g9@gP/f/YO//aMf4P//9K//9g9@/W9/5d@Q47e44//@V/@O3//61/7z3/z2t//qJ1//m1//yd/81h/81f/@q//nb/7nv/7vf/@v/9k30PO3fvJXf/Qrf/mNb/3lN//lX37jyxX3b914//I9/L/8R/B5fzzfB877lOtDfb78ufD5@1Bjngu0E2jdv/zuN38JGvhvMPbuWz/GMxbwW/H/Y02lOD/mb/8fcGjXy4whGXDB79fffes7SKL/AUgE/yG9vh2@LITwl2/PX4Csv70k0S//9Mt/@SN6ixmVOi1E4HBd0kqpDVBpNsplf8j21yggyS8tQgsB@Dl9GznUQti3kbe9@8HX3/3on777wW@9@8Gv4IAp5crp7bSk3jrZJuXfIx5GLLxPPIz4OeafomkkKfU5vLHP/cDPP/9caF0oeJjn7gX4fk5e/GI8CA/7@EFBGPrj6R92waJu35nxneu@b5gzYYG5pkjQ2AikoHyWTVM@QlPGFyvQHyJNN8g5xTv5YvBUwNv8f@6cCiyFcfiFHx0LnOTw0/lZcKeQh2xS03CJhMQyxkWhDe5DS56Ub67MsATTaWoK@i44IIcUBN1LsVqtlsKENY4PvHLU6iVGqKRSNSg3puZp0q0SgpjeIyiQspY6YK2N2pQnTCG8ekCOlIBeB6KqialS7T5kWJveZwgLgRPYly9r9VJtWkdwbzk9UtPUPcIJgdVS0/pbeK8RTEgnxO6/BVRKtVSqXsIMsZC8etItXkl5KhyVPcVSfh3AE3eub91l7GNRLYktLh0iwXhsvKfmsTEiRIfw49SGXxz6D5z02yCCr1FWfi6Mh2@RILrFZVOMAHAlSZZlBj9cS95idyF4ykGlKFt4pDiEFLUIagGhB8Npn5SQovpN0QvkH6ttfPCFwLAw6@vrQqwuZsV9mUinKMw5qdA2ftzZhopHhYmFsojeBp1pCHCB9FXKfz2Oq0VxxgGzj1P8d/fuBvsYiknPuZ/ApFTWztkxDmUzlRI1gF@3U8IL0EAEaKcE6EKQpzVSclJCOs2YXIthGNvf3/eRII8XNSEFzVzLqviOaySTySQGKWQ5LafT/lOmJ3nIvkOmUP8pryNx6QO2TNNyVVCUqgy9WFSrUUEBRs@3b99CrdBWocoe6KbM3zWk5UoUCB7clsFwOAvOvmi5ssD1cqYWcowlaPITriRLCizBNpIC32DOkQiuRFwrleIUD6gvJzaCTWQFlZoDTnzG6ohocHFlsZRPBoE7@2xn//Hj3SdH42aTCQZ9kNdojR27Y7huAsO2n9znhwu0ciEZazQQ9FFFQwYj7FYyxP727h/sHVYYL7RfBQlCrEqLhX4xy6oQG4@fb8b8TTQifmzKFg/xXpmXLaGVs5A0VhdiHQM1ClwFrtLmiarw2O3fs6eg8qdFMa0WUI1L0nQvE75mTxiaQuR2E6BP4ZEDeXOTKCDUzyWakUcn1FZBqNf97WdMFeqHu0eQ4GifqVpGFuqfs6mMGUqXQn1YGxpW3xus4z4u8TgjRsq03sik8U/LZuGu5gppNV9srq0NzyXM85iq7Rw35F3C67mExfgILiZ8JLCPwAsuyAN32TF/i@PeftXfZ4ZGhxJ8s5mo5qGbJYVjqGgOThhHLqBL7Mr6hhBb@@ILj9XroEpLew@EGHCLAQu2WklmVx7IVM3diWNQaJ@xrvmZiV8Rk7umOx7qM@g6QI3Y5eVlDyDtPWBaXaNXnqKL98sO@bTBfTnVhZhVqdTeqrmioJ1UKm@zmiaAh7Ch4F6uNWgAtDi@ofC/qguZZLMlBTiVKorwyGazAk4JC0LFEBjte3ibqdUk3gazOZW2PeDUgKJPa1p4@XGnH8/jZjM8LoZAAOt7DssEYUUe5r8VBHoDouFGL/oMatXvnJk7d7I4X5HNZcKJCSoxu4S6Wc/mskhx4f@/Fi9actkc17MZdVMZg1MHZ25T0cHZBmd@U2mD0wRneVMxwTmpZ9XMpjKpC0zY5PYHGZo3qImeMUVzp9xPrLvGsCfjeZmaSBlo4qZvz7ceJKx3a127Q98srnZlE78djacSeYJcTqzaFlrGquEZeTrHyRLJc6FfO6Ozk4JR68tobMGx9KHQldt2dya73myIJ0@GtlOLgzwYDwLm0A0QSHC@ayubzVUarCmP7fGWoOWLqYaagZEEf2opraXXjK1isdKVO0NDd7bylXwp3cVDLf461FY@U@nLnz9@9NDzxgcGnXTZypUhAZonQkMiW6VKPt9sNEQx1aBsmvgpVs6npLU16NyG3pXg2bMtz5W0UhMSd02nVovHt7KqJqmVbKZ0KcwJhzTHEtYFTJrCkqWR7uc@K6hYtgVcp5LW0@Y5UaHS6/UuN85T8xdBP5f4G9DnUtLT7fPwtSpF4lXYJC2Z80Dw0XtA7nN/Aa4iavmSWG1U5@/FglhtXgp3R0bX1PGAy3Hm/HqqAnBnDjUGGR0z4bLi2LZXaRs92zHmEbNqIYjIEboeISdehtkdZzDH8@vZFSKRpufXoeTy4mWYKkBLuLwEunNiQ7/gtiXrtA@0oZZzzV1gRY3mZmB1Eusm9uKFrtfrUMnnuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1GHLKuUK@BN0sU8jkNQ0A5MqlcvESWrQQ03WpXstqWUHTJC0rZVVJzeL/LQ4N/98/vgb/Gt4hVVYTjtB0wxMYy2D8tdgjPALu2ezIxo@A9Nk9o7Mixs5Apx2zO47tun@POPd064QH3Te5vcQw6KGOX0JyR6Y3WBHj2XiEVh8M5x8Nwu6oDQgia@IR7sHNGdr2sghF9uzpilI@Di0UAzG4iWKIfrD3ycOjyPNod3vnoVBg9/af3L/yyPuR8uzR7oOj8LXIQ4Ok@RDE13YfPbr66j9y@88OehPbwZ/wYP9Zbn4LvfBAppCDazFS6E1A/Bu@krSHM/trLF8MHKqA2/jvgMZ6x3fmC3NnBp3P@WlT0w23lfODxxXhKDiCqjPkem2DdbhxD1ShyfCWL2CrxbIgjJlln7FihnXt4VDHzzr31sBzoONxOgOlzCF9lRyzPrOdYffM7BprwmM8uVdW8RO6iITwEICMJh2ycgMSBppx7OIHl3EpqT2cGGyCHztf4QkP9EKnY/YHMB6e2UEEoa3rDH4fekF6I3p5N3t4PA/yuxYyvB5diAmi@FD39LuxEjBwtzmuZyqVO3fUp45Yzopu39idQoNlz6AD6c4sXRI9WXzA5Fasj0sMw4Kaz9njul4H3aABkjQMo1s5zaiXMvm//u0f/92f/HpZ69fU4/hxZifz@FG@AswRZEtG4qMvYsqkbGjlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU06GnFMojqGbWkFkr5spou5cogEuTKEJovF30BVQkkUmWjAmCtDn7TdZP0FXkAiglfO2RvEnqSxfTwfcJEA9KIAqqGHp1N3jBrMJoxNcOyRQYQddZhsQcPdjIPHojiPXzBPRM7GVHs4ku@lMkU74miQSE7JRRvRJunKaF1LNHjL5nMvR1RnHAAaFhaFAf4slvAyS1RNPFlZ/vBA8ynhy8apodoJzyEvwyDlyJEs/AF5GYC8DqEBtG2eT45QnQXXzBLDHnAQ3YgTBQ/CdDBkAMejQN4GJR0e1sU9/jL9jaG7FCx8xzRT/Flmy5RdOAF2r4o9sHRd6DXiWIbnNgDRLEDrs5MBz/8fi7aHrY8XRRnnDxIIFGcUmy9cyKKrcAfs/nMxyaP1K3Qi8pLfZdeyvgnilqANEbLhi9ZUcyFLzko28OHn@kDr2v0@TVz@LMDJX34MKub08nug/Ynn7T7/bYz29795ACDdnYegmgwmzjtfttP2G7BZUOqnYeafjKaXb2g1HutVkUfLg36tNXK6daVoNasZSCGkOo1YOZffcxo1NqBoJ2Hrbv6snVcAtjCzj@CZxuveyN43tPbPCi4KIie03ZbrGLzR7mdvmoPPZE@MJ8e6R3HruL7tLbGWDwRT88ahUyzSgFsBPJ3pnpJn7NP4F3HyZjk@awxrWWatWmtqPE9QL2EeDzV8qaYXhttqeV8ZU3fUrVcalpBywh2L87ikrrFEuqdjTcs8SS5pYEsLh5vbUliQ21uaWqpUii@2JiIYrKC961ssQIRM/EMY3hLNorNrWI@kqRYTOmKVikWk9VLoIcHo3kbJ0laicSZoZ8kk4guquxQBCorm1E5zWovMU1PaxwvNktWpzW1ys1tssw1WF207TzpeLbDIfYB3HQrU8HF74Solksi5K8oiWQSdWlSlhVhvtHw@VePTo6OPgdOyIS6P5XwlH@Kuuq/fvJwR97bD97QJrP8APUf25F3kF0thHCTwYHXEWgC8kMYPkGrCvzw/JljD@XdaccYoxIVBASWNmXfPqJ89HABzuHAPuM54/H9KhnZsjoGQ5PVZpfptTq49C5LEFZMT57RwN2q12ut2ohOuEMRg1SfMrLnPAez53LcQ6MClPwcz2T5Aa1a5rLark1jU4DTqjFJfTmyuy@1VKfaRUvV92r3MHG1Bc921agZjmM7Ykys9rasGmMTy9V7xlPDQXMZe/vrIEbgQa1EjxnJdXa8i7F3UF@4lOoOs@aYPZmMEiCQt5OLXpFXJE3iq0GRz@nkIO6NuKz2aizxIll9Da/OOkt05XvJrVy1m7jHWknwybzsvewxjRVyVfqEbAIhQSci2mCZ9WSt/ilIPhzwSaUCiPh1fAIwMScAa3YpQE@OzctqpzZkCYlNWZLIk6v2aw1MfYG3TUkUm5LUuGgKdUl6LtShn1ZnMb3mTtr0eQOWaataplCdgp9azFUHULH6i2nVqY0njlEdwqs/r8YPSOpVICdQDcC8uUi8@6WvJzelfI37VQnUxRCEjZbcqk2rFhpMgyZRy9YgINXIZdKgQ8OtmIZhXiuk1UI6m86lpSL6whifzqfBE/QaECkSw4TImJjOTDOymlYNNZ3IvDS7L5PpkwTIKkQylkx79q41GTHwgUrCVkmv8NRZMqVtDBnUgs30TYmaKXCKKhYMaD5gYzM9QFAHhj6kFMmkxLIbieF6AuOsH03Gu41mpbI7HX8VghLS661CqphJvUkmq4m1ZM01Xgv1qlBHrkKlHq9Bm/WnHJk7GTWgjsGlFrVKo9HGIhYz6WwmC6UzWxf9TbEuNtOZtYIKVXTJSDxinGNEZ@FQyJn7jVsobw8NqDq1rFUFmabEsiVNKiv5jXyGT8vxlMLYZ2tISZY4FoPDwIl4vKjF48l4FRcE1kR/Bhh4GfGxODDV@B11SwT5S6yIZQ0jzFkinffMBNiBBHYp4PQDy5WF2LlweX65CcqwQtsmQWBka@SS5PpdIVZhDMTAY9/8kLLG2Ifuxkxt1l/w5zFuOQe4Alk2BQmUdkkZJipg7DM82r7F4oCY7owampZtNrQiDGTAHIOooIZXcQ0khnva5TpQ2D0H/DZTdTwV9imbzfSUFEzK32Gsn1oXqMyxq@uc27Xt/sF2sAdsewfneY9BwharcTF2Ho/FL@FPiN2lo2gaP4rGYpHDaHye/xfid2PxeBwn1IFQb2PEI9jOeTD/VcEPbSX0CucIjWby7RNzeF7KSnxaAljU5WVsXaGaCQ4DffpSg0YRs@zAAzQhnDGCwSqfx8nqmPJy7H6hlbKP9/at@84Dg/GzQaVcS6zHWEaV8IhNteL75sXW2okKbSIrZk/SMXY3RpvMxXJJEzXuUY2xEymuVvh5ovFh@UXxRenF42f7z/YfCLHjtYs1G9clWLhn7q31la9CxHg2F2fsuBab1nJVf8dcvS6pmxpa/CqyCrD7nlqQMhd13qzrFFDQIOTdL30/N90swbuWUeFd0/IprV5XNzSWjI3fffn7aLzlfPez7UcsjrPZf/cnP9KKf/cn/5p2ocUvaYZbyxZjEBOdaqEYOz8fn59fwsXD8rFmjCOVKybBzVdb1FhdUbWsZVlVVlF0faOYyml3rarix1WLajLmSjF/3aiYj7kXfpCWKUFQsLBDXmIBqyS2e2DmNfXu5hYUZyub06pr2G7U8AgjC/82DbccE2Klxy8vGIOXTr3b75sauRSFVd5KbPOttMne4qrKW2mNvazVcVVexYOPwarDBh4Jw5W3eD2lbMQZ6EGs3risXjZTtG4BCuMLw9iwjq@0@uM1PM@w6LVhwZ@x4dIfJgo8XHgN3oyNV66Y2EgqSrcbmgjbNFi@Ds1iQwHcNoKlB/4nScfJd7/0m5pW@Ls/@bWL1kXrcw00x3K5oGqxn/1sc2JNXKNb/xkkvMEsR6D90boN2s9AR6g1Mm7D0fRThQ65AwrrxEIxmccPdEjUGlHIMPsWKP74JpyiYEQ12eKW4boJiraBp/bTJGaTJaZkVRBCcZTEaKffSRMMtoFG/qBrC@fCRxgEoy@rAdcVPpqDAo8RjLd2p@UOJ86YTn8kKJ3aTLM7kARy@AiN7q2RtQGfdUvA7pSN60k5yi5RjYQoNjJcF034wagjfARJfAOowxkb62gYA2OaFowVMkYhPCmg24C8m5D3kCdokW@CSs8jpBnHjieyQNQWPgLpgahgglDBzE2IUAW@9BEQAMqQ8AGbTbbJskl2bqZS1bl9wEvcAY@2EvXgUL6AyRBaF41ABImrGA@8QMTHT@5hu/BrGOS5iGcAhMPgq@g1UBIwOb2hlEZWM94bFMAiC1UJKhq7c2eOVa1mdpOMSoTwT8wxTm9RPVjLcQVggYL1cbciphlaXqwGvmGzA4qnCF1odRI3uViNJGUivl4KAvy/d6PFFnmlqiigigXw64v3ig6QDBIj2XkddthmjalaMclC5DuAe4eQorPRodZ4PP1Y1j4PAi8Bw5/Fgg9aAIs6ik4Z@u32qlUGBqPmBL8mgLa5ODPwrSlw61vI6va8IHWYCopiDil2z3RAo6Hl/cDwXyKrJjHZ3FAi4UH72rUc7gjX8kl8UCqMzeCpowE7P581MrzTsaFC3bFtkcU7ssiDW/ehRQCP8o2FcbQn1hl@fcavG0ocxcglQ2HY8hFjsuBHn@2ltLi@3nZA7Q1ok2ZGX2adUZdpZZaghkZGzawQXJISEcJtEI@Rxu2hMQKUDg2DTmO5FUXpg3Q1aZNlt8cmtKvBAxPGG8tV/C8kK2fmiakcofV8ye7hoS1uJyOGAhl2P76U71tRG9r2CRuaJwafCU4sWBlxGSgIIOOmgbLzHxC2gntEtGyaZSA4zWPBrwiPIneW0pG0a4lZ8vozq64lWlijFzT4mA5@/fhUtyL0petC8HVid@YGdorI2g68yyHLNXwLJbU42h4ITe8IvsWlGhn7kXGFYZwADTWwVIROYewYpwy1WwHHGGCancDmB/ZiKO1HNABQ34OehQYMPaeClmoAE6eb6EDX8xm8xT5mWU3AiNyMlG/yCWBg1dcWoUMYJMVyuF4XKkamaXXkK9A7R10IQxsJfvPD9EHrRjcZl5w3b7bmg8NBh/KqMd4tgpd85AV7B7ZnKvoaBBYAwyWYrCXEFIBNiUmRgw7TX03OW7tAvKTCrkNKM4TgkxqgkKgQfB6dRT4TI0DAPd3ltsR984ZnZ2cy2dycOKZsuPjpFBe/@a6M@yaI1LbiGaOx/5FKEz9O7MOduyT@xSR5PBhvTVF2rZXvzPhTEHpuzd9pk4j33DgOjqf4ZZD@iOxzoWEslxrUA5O@KtRJ@Bt/ePvTmunzoP1VsP1JpfglAmEMwUzTs3QnDcDS7c5JunfWrfoBp9QhATjUohF4oiVcJ3gZuYHLHPfCGLaHfDQMag9PaM0UIIl8DneeNS9hEHMWvPrvY3MKiSzjjG07jj5LUHgSY2MDTsxI7GEzGPYpBJwwzLBzbpbVnDZmzYXk0zA5DGrhjgEHjW8J5zcD5TZ6MXzKw6cQPuXh03mmQbaNaZOLZOh1icXBVo82G4OYCGYWxLnk9mznIQQZpG@mchAYc7bgdwm/To1SB/Tmb1CPtaBhQJsYA8GNhNJ4cdw4blqucbbRTCl9aOwiEQJqHEA3mkTTs27oRuoPT4dj213wstBUJ4xKPt7o1Rn4rYG3FSxjWEHUMDi9TLSu2B/5Wxu4QOAXGCCgHAaBKBpsewkzWQ1tQlMgNJyGOKcxR6zhI9Mk6csP8v1AXOKk54SNAmpGAKF/WCRAE0JY0HP4h7IC7vDcsSFOEFeib/uM0MpXvBkHSl7pKpzXVKmSIlhJUoAmkB3F1drVogThUBWNK0GRYl769R9Ff@2D0e9Bv1iOPTVYPmBUhWhXwW2FIEL43YWoyuq1SL0CBsqGPjQcGLl2uXzqj9aQzYYSqBk8HyyCe4Zf/05EKr@T5PVDRxdFS6yETWFWq0ERZzXeLXm/CEjKCR4mc/1ks6Ah@Ok5AwEYmaXJDD/ZNJpsWqtxxsGmK5KdRZCcEpJTnoTHnq5AsuknA@1pLxhesHqaIJ3ivkcR4Kl8GAUxaCwy/AQ4Lnq/QguEuFjq5znnOdQK/DaEIja2s05zae6NCNIRpnUFADbEawC6/JubFeEqw1Ol8C3kUZyUAY/ib34z4LwCGhix4Cq30psIGxnpwCDwiykaB6DviqmGIKo0EYx/Gf4T04Fn8FOve2YWY6qLnpn0lb9/FM8mUjbSQSPSh5rJIUNGTeaZ5Zu3jMocMfw89cAGqa59ZrPEEmEb/JWJn1RpD@22MtJx8wp@ic//Ov14lgz0B1xEYXfHtqd7di5X4UqTSc1uWf5cZzD7lo0f8IhY6gZZr2sbrhX3oFI7dt8yXSPN0IjiieGrHYb/kQIhKif7TtsVBH8Kk6uxCJq3KxR1Wy38NnCrlcCdgslKuP@ZNg5i84zHBdR/wRVJD@zJB7o/TtjtV0bHS94OE83O@8mOzM5JYn/sB@J06zYDHtYB@R9CByDBMNeea45k0hpF6baXoK9YDOyR3Qepb@LKAqa@An5vDhsR0sdjwiXNdFRpK5GPD1AvSXTSetJP@ukHJ2Wfagk9GabXFgEsECPNnKs0Rso6S7JrrcyOJwvyO/xwfA@j@B7ejC9p4Vdx5qp5jQd@WNbZxBwCRJyjkb0dDSw68K3uNXQWUAm9Ua7iCd4bxS5tDusiptsQdduPLvegfaTDNxfeQsQ/W0X/myswSL77vtWn4wfTD2fAb0a46TFB31xyg9XQBETfSyLvuZ5d2LTvv2deEBc/d/cARQgQY4lxWWiNFzrmGNRuN5wuDgDf0uZxP9a1dk@btGo8cAlOzmmanWirq@h@q2sM9ZnRTfgx0xG4QYkPQGEjfvV@BUdGR0zP5rpeAsauZBgKwzgSnUeqrGgyevo0mVzdrHgUM2w9NFNOGO6tph@GX2PNOMVX47PVoAfE4zGcjj01cfpzPBvPuMH3If/yjs9H@fjDaxLtM9xOEKADHz3V9Dzb5E3s8yARFuk9RoQwrrxYZLTHHEBEm0PX6/DDSHR7SaFyI4lqQS0Li586WV7j5k01HmkVQZvky0zv1yRva3Tv3eYiTY0Dm7OwnQ8bQq5Bxg0cnU4iCpH73FhjtnWNJ6AfzdNZK0aV1hKGGqYkTueZpG6TfJEUUDPegydOOH0GTwTYN7wWb1BB2XBOy/@GHaOQkT6OSC2@DwjpACVCRU5yH41ILCFwQ/TzyzDPzso8O9fy7CzkGfaAxSwjkYTOQpZ@LWD13FQFQ6PnreDOGIS6MzxuYttwWbbu4GzFedyMV8w0i5/GK8CQ40a8spsAphzvxiv3yeHGK4fkOIlXPgXHvG/FL@KVoFtgBAdeyXEX/X0Wju@deGUnkbwUPP3EcIN85XglrFOIs8VfiSJACiw3SI24xGbZfjE9x4CBjYTKNMMW46ZRfaJ5mDT9MvDPP15EnzXBQJzj3KDILMXUhUEjMmLwfGDYCMzmL@nJFX80391/QBugwiiYTQp0vGgaAg9ieCy@yIw4YhhKKxrwBASRb1aWY8QiI9l7ouPnDi2UKnkxf6KeTPJAN0HhDYjcnGdCX6zy0wf1tQiCV@D74YmJV@F5DZ0gO8II12STS9BCor6M31AorOtFXPzaj9YQzXUvRgJspSAKryUCG@HpIMPR4hxmNrbHi42EQnGLvRlNQ5NyvFNi672SjLiC3zNXBJO3XzJkDNHOn7ypOJF0iNoCC8LARqbJe1k4LhAvxqA5r4tIqrzzAQoRngM93Oic0NfA7vtOisfZTZrGilXDUJCWZ0mca5FNQmIZDV5NdI/nHiqvu2gG68PU1yDlFOdaEgggkjLMhfNX@wPkd5vL74FAHRDhSgbLBOvlQ@l18frGUfYK5sN5ttcrEAPT7H5yqXAU5jAnOWgHEcn8prZ2TcTHLR9cyOeZhtCvSPsB2UKd4Ba6XdUtOCyUEpzTRc8TDTxPtNWEui6RDE/lQGiRMScfDi94iOm8aDfjygu@rIoxhOa39eEHV7CzWMHRykN4VADnCsl5L3cmFu1ymfdtYNvcB1mqWmGckdNyaVjNc09g97R0Gy7bgsd@6@D@/pNHX4NBt1gsJv0xejbHD3stzrWG4ziHTLupw/FgidqipfGTPbjYjdPx7sB2vLVjS7zGSzizBmFAh1yC5uf38aTPyyL8/ErfhXQ8boSiPqyTeTfQF7gSijo6DtmmT1cPCGJ4iQ3dBxKIt0DvNGlrSfo4Tatl6SOj1aLhq9XCzUutlj@KYdUEK@LJn8XWlInr0Ddw@ZeVzgSBLDuw@/vs@cPtI3b0cJc9eLbzKfva/jP2fPvJER7qf/rs3qO9HQa/3SeHu0xY2GaJX6FDhRLoet/oGPhpUaZlMjlGkHfs8YzzncROkvsf6iP20O4YuEy16eqjuwP@IluGV@epdkEdneEcpklfHRyZHu63oM/kgRqLwk2XjgXi5n/2/xR3rVttLMv5N/MUbQkbDYxu2GBsIWwBwtYJBh8u9vYCrC2kEczeQtLWCJBss9dJfuQFkv95hLxK3iG/8hRJfVXdMz1CYHyctY7XMpqZ7q6urq6uvtWF8p7SnvYCe96LXitoB5TXwd63H/ihsSRTnYB6kOStMWz2ZJGEiHisOsSRLqGBdU3FG5QfdzcEpiH6VyAxckgIvVZOacJF/36YggfVvXf7Cv4hNnZ3NmsHtd2dfbW1u0ev7z/Vdt4QPWv7B3u19UMkccZ3u5u1rdpGhT8IAoWcguOG3y7D4b0o5JCdqdL8HTffuT51f/SWPPXGCl5dN9hAMlRzl11In6DRCb74rbmScxli@QKjTL4qUJnZyt6bDzTnK/8P3HCaq2DWP0gdhhylcbagVrk2GixrNN5KjvHEmMkWXb6PuBgrBGrxS@zQIcPPnjLAWYmnFfgqtQEdFZx9i98HHssGNFX0iGADlFFYKSsOsDQ3560yyDWqrdnpwUWn1CZKhPoFRV8bVZOSwxTTujIACgOHWhfnQcVS9IH4nj4s6mqHA8mgnkYfJIN6Jh@wFK1Bd0Qt6RyXw91LiGe1LB9@u@hv8bWweh59WG/wLnZF4yT9xl3aUFGAOnjB6HAYLTnl4VCfjbAZBFwk5PwIMdXpyMDwJbghyUS5SmTdNsqZImHTxlWDVnuTmMFIJW6AnlCjPQxVpuzm1AGUg/xuIAHMzjqNrqhAxao7zHtqBQ6Hymt6@RAF/mKTkX6PGRBBB5N4ROU29arQf2g5Krl@q8aG1pHk4JtGBe17CKzfQuDvAUOAsomdTpNnKrZZBZheW7NyJuwRR@Lc9k87P7Fz67LpJwpora3Mb8GXL64mspfYJxk9RcaOuuiLP6BlJV9ltnsDGuMsVjlUEqRg87zXHwbSh5lkC/jGiac5yo2JjWr71RBX1wY6TNbY7XWtSk@Ji@@o9ZSY8iG1MsfL3XkkvuIYusT5NAmL3h3QaZz2rnzr7szDJdK1j@MXWgjzXTkOP8dDxkTWn04sO/5UCL25Ul7bXD/O/vmrh/ibIhYk/K1ROsR/YkzURcOD7/lYYXGAdZceaSZuWnh5itJaB09LS4xyA4z2gecB7ete10tRmqgb3/4Oo5rJ7/zx27eylMpCMumYyeF5JpZunjoyVXpc5kRpFRBLdhKyJOsz5ovHMCN5/RqGNOgFeNDpQo5g3z4RlUyLENO608s2SRYdHFZ3dwTfVWusURFH1oaBjN0f@c@Z9fLCmpuPFUqURc6MEdGegVx0XUstheerW@A27wdH8vvh4FbuxU6mhx@CtnkvtB/CLbtwNyyZlixYDwf75z1gZXL7u8BS2727AcskeRtaxOkRc3qz6Uib9v4af73Vdzz2CAzmXpygRECt2i67fEVtPGJnpIBrg4kXRPsHm9W9PZWS/QmVJbmHLUNLi0HAfqTex9q2QZeFXS5aNNlurGXxZL4kNNrMv/sG81Ti3SEq9BrE0/SIhEUc5qYdjETq6ZmFlxCsfc8C0VAuid1XI4PCIw34hvaAhGzcaVYDnanNTMvkE4S2ErimmydrY1uHnzWsZe5GyNXB2AZk6wQ1zmBZMr3/Psr6@KWpRxZY8DaEBrdoJU3zDe0T9qniPmXM5ZI9eE@3mC6Fkr0ssNOGdlD8KiRX2D/PUMxIsgiXtbAl1vXiWKMm6@NZs8xhhURMAw1oeupE0WimBCPi@cuq3aFuPOllklMQLTIRhPO1zRVU/ORGT2FMjWieLEcLcnuszTI2RwbLE5zOatiluzM9hi708qR4mKyKpO29VWX/f6qSWSJRk6H51MaYRIK8vLT09HuwJ1thimd/FrbMIZPyc3jRp/19DDIch3y8T5xb2/FMeswA95BOVOvNgJkoSEudKXNKou08Gdn4ES5yLkTIwD884ppO1uqq0QRu06HLjGRD5yy32mAN4aihMmpuUf/m/uogkL9b36Mfr08GGzJBdfAGWvnveoPQj63yLGcu1ieYvya/@YNBl7OJPdMFoGTYjOleYzu2thOFV2kVEvm@zW5JW1snidqtZ84auBI@XswhlDFO90qTx3vZYslu6lZtu6rm2W9kO3EWmRqkXEv2PAq69yHAMpjPJTB9sA3f4/Al/SccPAOSyMTWfBmmjftd3JgitGo@4vhAWi1Uy9biZO@3w2ajCx8gXupxqFLeEyrIp7DV3S132sl6oZQoT8iF/W6GSnmpbC7FRekbDnQBKQlCehPfrQkLlhpGUxLmNWc96EfhYssfyekZa0428sWVwvILh1vX9YbexdGLE2@@WU4pmnwb3YvwcnDd@v2sd37VVh3V/@101Bx/@UOppWfqKdW1@ESc9xaXy3n2l/qc/q6oFwXmXI3gK3ZEjNC6OYk5qtScivfhpUdKIo/wpvklLCQmuFTNXxguhIndsHxxtHxS7pYLpYuj7kkJRn7DhfJwobiQwYcnNIuSjJGb@aPhCeZU@9TV714puMjkKJfaNESxaQh9edcYBL3tys6bxGkcFgA4AtO63nygLmGMZ6DNBtuTXNe/zuhjMk@BYx0skJwZtgoqwjaez5NxHNMKCDPqFY9Ws@GI/45dZ6aQu@wPe5xi/CCCtdS34JszY8yYCnyiQFmOAuMtEfYFBCfOk8HFkHwdixZ1tijLtSJsJ10LxBFKsjhMHadSsCkEotqW6@jECXN@o3kOJBC3@xsXU6urHMWbWC3M8SkeVDkaAzaYKJzgERcg9NPn2wZUwSv3kM0@HGo@3ot4kC98RjVkOxlWkHd4pYgUqH@rr2zfxOVXiQBC@BlZc@X0EadeedFCUmwH@XABjs2SG39cM8CsUjplBo0FbKmvHANnTXGmEarVZKLvM9cgp9CK/ukWZIv8dqsZUX5XsjNJ@J5av4WgJXcpJ63hpxMXy1jFsqaYyWyRYua71MBJF22P3vk0rMZqw@90CGmhxUxMDjyyfa@ufyGqPzxCnScR8pKevZWeTaTnJF2QinPlaIKPM720M6XSX@N8NyoVZ/Nu1VVWvHjJUU83c7QkifOW7ssb5oa9ehBnXou6UrgySlhNJGStlM9Tel9SHiXKRAwepR9JuubvRd3zEZaJvK@T9ePX0R3ks/Ks1jWZ4NJcN@i8cnTIZ50CNksRNZWS4hyZUJlBVdY2mFqc0AoO5/w8bNfKMZSFopE4PGZSa6uvUzm9yHiVmURDrBhvDawpY8SiEte5wIQbscEi1cPJjywQDBOMpszIXTOFx7rw2AKLXI9MtWIFeWuAU9Mmh3gZdpHf8McM9iRyJl96euKMYD6Sxot1c5JALHQfpaaTKSlNYC4iH3Wj7plF4rrHkxCnC4kd6xQ4qtMXG@w2jsEfRXLCFhRGUtyie5SiKR1nKBr2vasLkXjj/G9@3nnToDV2v@OPVAXbjAZbYTkJA/ehHw5DOINinzbhZb/fwa0jL/iu2YRa@xVZXMJ1SwzRmtlzTg2aPZLfw5M2SKdCObULyNdQEIkTwsuzMxiTwQK2dw3RihOXYJhzKt2xHGjQmHm6KGbmvoLzDRbAneDMRkJ6TkYPKB32G00/59AaLaTVjyNNbQc6oiefp8NuBO7GaEp76Th/vQyav2@8wX3u82LhadEi2ZW@Di7knj6LDayISCZhEa4Cl4rPHMe6G27K3XAWAD21jYn@A/Gmf@V3u75ToRmDM4a0aA39wZXfyjnOnh9dAgMuWBk3k7DD7l0OmnK4Q4uuBjEjrIRDT67DiMPwi/lZroubfFfmObi0im@bqauvghYIaCxO2j3cDvOFBdwECD1Q6MIfElHmXZVEie@eNS68drnAQRRRA35OrLuJiAzd3jBoUs/wSZbTIVByDRJX1m1NYEL1NTsNGAfnpiEA85iYAgYBc5V0Hw6OvjT/IRyUbpi5Y2@YnsmT9OvxWKHh7g8Ckr4xgblXuJiFO3Xwwdvavtrf3Tr4WNmrKnp@v7f7obZZ3VTrn/iOGxfl7HVXvd3dJukS3abLrfkufUhV9qlkihOcys4nVf3l/V51f1/t7qnau/fbNYJG4PcqOwe16r6najsb24ebfPtOENTO7oHarr2rHVC2g12PazXFnLic2t1S76p7G2/ptbJe264dfOIat2oHO6gMt/oV9b6yd1DbONyu7Kn3h3vvd/erCg1zNmv7G9uV2rvqZo7qpzpV9UN150Dtv61sb080dPfjTnVPsZKA1cr1KmFZWactLGridm7W9qobB2hQ/LRBxCMEtz21/766UcND9ZcqNaey98nTQPerfz2kTJSoNivvKm@ocU7mO1Shftk43KvCXRIosX@4vn9QOzg8qKo3u7ubTOv96t6H2kZ1v6Sc7d19JtjhftVTCF/IVRMMohal0/P64X6N6VbbOaA54/A99B1c6uSPRBjCskJFN5nAUINAa4lIu3ufABV04A7w1Me3Vfq@B5oytSqgAjQqNg7sbFQhEfHAbqbaqb7Zrr2p7mxUkbwLMB9r@1WXOqy2jww1KGR8ItahSg@51egnwkseiVkdw7ked6eqbanK5ocaMNe5iQP2a5pbmGwbbzXNc3DKax2iBD2cGTQu7IOV9u1PVz68Ud4@kZl@RhN5TNrY3azSjKx9W6XihEOadVYmXCnZaTTTRIn0mnBZ0/JPL8/qQbfdg41pVEwOPi7CMw@RelyEOTl27glUpc9XuEA6Xa9/qNRpo7tfr7veQ0om0PheCX0Mfl8uV7cR0Q@w88bBz8uXQvfVBKHWnuiLTlbUwwUEcgr1n4jqW@PCd1U@3/J1MRjvA7A5Ogrl2uQcVykkGtnYEfFZ4ir5ZILfA80OXDBjwOeadZyTQjOSM/VC@tP9Fr/I5GB9IOksx135PDaxjEbwxTfVSCXsEoH/aI8EQZurzIW@//tZpmBXhz1/7qzXa2Vc15ThvEPaB55l3O8UP/XPJopnJ8szsnztrAMHhGbfzUuY6P5Zk0zpfskNuGUZ/KkP@cc12IjPB5yaclV8WK0PLTNPpDg0kjylXVvAvII7GWu@d5Vfah@xmyssPitNfH8bfZexBX1BeK2lCe@Iy53wz9sTyUADjH1xEEkC7SEjn7fKGH2TKPM1ZTxHpuugBc0fmqvPfZ7XiSS0kL1sdOw6MRsPgpGNPcnhN3uVd@uHW1skOoHts5Wl58slJ3K79Ysnv59QD7uWZa9jfZrHaZ3GSdYo2aCFD48Uy6V3zP7MwPk8MsJbu@k0/gg/D5HeRlKTCYIMzQ0RrKgLFb2UDzqkFDvgeOQYfp06MjUDZBJNddGai8aIl/gNWisxD2hlls6Ye22EP4AdDX8zxKMGaQbSLMbOdolzaXfBci@1ZVRFeXPDjnuQJZcyfCxu3CIa8FEX68/CupbfNG9bvRiKKiPGK3c7lyQkHk1ioYxeRVdG9nv2M6IPgNl7GH35RfMbPX7SDu7Y3V0jHFaG@0TGragkzqnjw2jd6CMN@QSRM@BUzdS0qnDK72qkeOzp4@TIMYg1GhgVhGWBjm8ScCnyIzJZJWvAvp5z1VfhVDjvAJyS5lj9Tpw7rTkaSsn4D9HvxiuFEliRkxOh2nVUh2OyfIr8WBhyJsj0U/Rg@P9AmkyBv0o7ToIeU8tyAvggSjJUoRVtX5kowbW5aLBuN2Jq2p8@xWBu7I45jxqmb29GYl9DJNC9MzYfPrHbw3ZmCgHA5DjYsMdvpJJ23qCt0@uUq4vjnqTbvOhnlJ4rzFRxC252@cTjZZdn7lbw4ipXzpqsCrepqHotG7dTHvW0ZZrYyqvHYUrAucb/R36eD0CiAc9cei5aq5OcVdCjzMgB7WrJmnBakcckWpbe3HlrN68sF5kJ2a9vvgyhCPQa8LndTg4j0lOinpv0uMgzsTpgL3hwII5tMiYf7bLulBUxOz7gPG7xYQgijQyvMUF0BDq76ouhqcxjVhRBJbHWYexnEOLWzRFpeVq9jrDnk0lwaIT9YVc81/tyqmVy5MTBh8bQNpfPqXeNMaHceVizhcXy8/s9D7qLqEyOJXR5RFVp9noDWjo20G7C0QvGbk591IcOfje8HGj/hTSfBQN9ImEW/VQNlk2ye@dpRpzGM2phMIS1QivH/MFNuvChISruSUbZZZUh5jU8umYOHYPRQlFlVuOUVaIJuyVlIq6qZfXtm@QSgmqXoT5TMAijzQXrbHI9uHeIht91b/A75n4sgbotvxV5JrVA8lmgdFKtyz4em0Nper8X8okGdQVOQCJKFOUgLVJUpTn6uWYnrdeUir1jwncpt@TH64mY1GhLUUUx4@raifmWs9SZoNKidg0aOQstLi4xKtM2XDd3bsbYW2jy2lqljruRSHkpi4jyY7N0xJPIzejpE570IX/5cYjRQ19wx62XoEAYa1bcq96Wc4wfdAo@Bv6gZZ@J0kqm1ejj@I23Pr0u86I5OtRu/5qNYeiPaQfQzAejPMOoZ/7SO@/WN3qdxlnQCxq0T4Pf95FIPDyO@REddjboXYccMIgTWlam1jh@Fv8y4oYN79G9ZMlyzRUO/X7GVlMYDsaVc3ETwSfnUAKMI4gyf/cnfaRFZZ4txYWcpP0p6@MV3dKdZZ8WpxWWG30A0AJubUKDQmxIh2yYZBmflm5lOL0vg4XjqcqqhnuHxl4C4xdEIr6GSWBskLmllmA3AjuzOzE@ao28FvsgHMDRkr/pI/ZNmOHPXgNBmUmKvIKmwEtVXClYReUWZQQ/hHgY303uxef/YOwJgZ9Av/h0GrdMYwQWcW3jbSmU/Yr2Mkq4sHpgwDKaJTFJseAs6Frmhxx1YjQJNZk8vosarPlDiyLtZu8WV2JEZmjjg7h2mTqJnPrYxaQyp@Zc9tuBJUhlmCnczbD@9/RnefDjEldOziCYNjTkjIX0XaRqEpUQ9nZCvdZGWXwqf3/ELC4@tNcmCFiepnJmhV/OpMzKhS1QAplfca3VG5AwTk1QT6t6zIXDXn/ugdS7U3ZM9cw2jdZN1/2uIrAwW5kmy/kWk7Y8xuO45EziM8E0SYqxphnxELav/Byx@SQRR@U6xlu5Pv4OHe6iWaw3FU0qUX@3ZOxjUryCRq@ZaKIhxbjDSWkp@n5Up4bX75YgGqZsr@osMeoQGfWxPFqgJsgUUenhFGLu07hP0KNFlEO9LaKd3T93EnVSSc64PDVJCSeXoCcct8Nok@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@6hFhJOGW/3wG7muMrA/hu/@nWGs1Ug4mOFcB@6YyxS0Y2hLxiTWGqR7Ow0zWe9iIHBWZP22urDwdbWwm3r6djo2h04Q@WCoUCmPjUdn5vdKtxlBT08snc@fZlp5PvX/9l8OE0z7Lf9zkkwEuzg/apS2hQhLne4EwiQwAHyorcWW3Iir3@Zbtth2DADSU6j7pNcmpvCIonoCBSevlwwAdADFJPsL@igWjfryoafdcNWWhqKOYaikpDJfgqZW7PiDz40IZ@dnRTxcAgmI02E81bbnntK2YQRDbhzmL3xe7XWD059dbvdHqe@oiQw/AUMHMzWWBryy5QkCy4YWTr3suQ/dF6yr8KOpZdMbLYvA5wZmIycSaMX3j4xt/zz6qjfiZ19DlF0wo1eQHNXIB/ak@lzlKudhb/ALDCh4T2g3JfNPqZJtNpMjNN9XoEx0@E0dOiN3Xvk8ji8pmYptn3c4Oo09HNsbMGarrLawHjy567l1tyR/aIuKnjUbENGhYEhsYJPlceVgKmZv84sXg1bLcfJhU5DIB07A9JRImE8nMCke8AeATq4Uf0hBftf8rSsN6acCgiCxwE67gtd1CgjgKO87hZ/uM6U6lU1Gx/YUFVKuv0kM2qynpFbeLD@rrapPd1vD8pLy4tlUTmbrpf6eO6@Xij1gkGn3AuNM8Hm/RKaWXYjUFbG108my/PeqXZenl1rRTmjyrrMOunp//@53/973/5t3xFv/wHXtb55ehzlCmXy@Vnm19nn9yU8H60eTI3e3o02z@ZOyuBy/6XvYb3asNsI1YfzQ1OnbTMAtZX1iM1@2z2PqOLKhMU8KIx@J2ky0uVbob5tP4aSuQolrHppm9992FHeUpbeBN0YHIrT0ikCegYx/HUO00fCng03xAlCRfogUp5uVsxB/dwBxNliG5V0toTD69Zr3zYtMSeFGCLSzNWNuiGfhcn4Fe85pXmOU6DfoNhXfNv/vO78Gy9N1Lzxxk1X1DznppPpfinuPyCvrqz@QDWuZKNtgOplEcp8dUC1AxVGPBCj/cPHGtngtyOM8shewDJuKngzGIF50W7PzaWkYBr4Zkzg9ibSo5I@JIJRdJfZ7s31C1fKcdNKmFqwwuFut7FcGXWjUrUv1gCNUJRBIhrvhCCvOxRlbjpY4tkPOXNF93XDkcTYsAg696bLR73@EBz0WxX6zwn9lIIc8Tq8/IVc2NJjKEZbaRI/TECfKEi28kCWxLOpecc0fK2WsnNFCtsu32a@UTXYewPjW66FPpTWUwg2tw24Wa72q5FK3LL9YpKBdH1ilVValL3WzlWkYvLzjDoa3MFrh0D6mtU242MJPQoAxI44rP/5e0RxgcFxlPURLdIsKyxavXQdBkJXW2aTh3s5uTmyCJC/nOGxva3ibHt5tlKxLCD8AAjFanytRtBJ9ReVwZM7LPG4BTRARttDqg2lHszPs9DuNUJjHvtCOkcQ2aV83g8U1PS/UHj7KLhqfRO72DQGNdo2qKVz7CZc6mFcMEEJDD4dNXTmmcQlhbpLmGKRE1hzSEEL@iMdXg06dtUZHOCLjVDQbtdwSBIsBNT0v@W6KsJOsZc/QOdYKN8S3hHt5FaxLLkhaaRhpSyzWZ4mN0aOo6pwR470cBJOYJqNDINL@hCl5hoL/jilyR5Bz4CdN0pbQWoTRGWX6B@zE5nfreRmJz6HccY@udLSuZFjGcORSnaSI4JlFqMI94BK1pHfk56gZC5ybgzcmYymZnjUIdzS9vzCDv5jnTx8w0VRAHoOIAZW4aow24gwnJihopjYORUjTX/CUK70zgj/MbXjTFY8TidefUo7x59Pu6ezGeOu9@Ov7iMiRbJZpbNqrS@zDYSS48VmhnzXuLVaKWFxtXgcTeZ4birxIbFIgEhks8cfc6ffMsTQsdpBKE/TgtBEl0GTPL315cH@PwtNNNJLPJpZ8add03nZ14VXUVzK/@iD@WDK7@EhdlU8jE97XMGbQLFdrp/XIrJSZhfWSw8Wyw@o53QmT/KDvxLzLfZ8PLUH9FSIsR2lqae4y8JbkgQ4mYUNkr0cUTtlLAmYnsSaiMlLUL1MOd6nIitqExOeILyE5XZXSpMXNwoTwOXj9jwe4pYzuRlX1CiOmhxXwbzZ9i7QD2NEHJt0jpEOBJaBqIjwkeoWUA2wVfu4lDXDJc5tnPKqQ34bmUg1L35tDVbdHvdrF6subm5EhbRsJrprBRWCpNj9NYQTYzQWb2Ymnukimuvnv/Xv@/@kR6m1xbzHwf0O0z/kV5eScsjPdDbU/N2lV5LryLb8k16nKc9MD0@/6//pPJrfyE4SBmv0p@1JQNreZxey5a5yLf02jI9FBcXqd7/@dvfqA2zsmNDLNbZuqcYsZKhyEajy7xL6aqGVsq2dC4WK2yYBRiiYUh7c3qBYtRocaXAx3RprVVx5WvPV0YfRU/xrJg1ZFUhOckw@hS0MpICZVSQFZBGhaKtLN0No7YB5o3RVL8@zi2HtAP4VatzRFVGqhuPQ6gMzcq2iDowIzXSfl4e1gqvUpF6x8uU0SkpmSUktnZa1q48Lf0f)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2u7q5)

litehtml treats any unknown `@media` as `all` ([link](https://github.com/litehtml/litehtml/blob/051b5a52/src/media_query.cpp#L91)), so `@media x` does the trick:

```css
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}
```

`}}` is on a separate line for Flaks.

Answer (score 3):

## 349. [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 15866 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11 xxxxxxxxxx                           #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print (349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl6154op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92=1*\0ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c9tadiD4Y6qR@SOuQD2TFAmAAL9JkbIsy896z7bctvz8uimaBkmQxBMI0AAokZbl6u7Z7U0nmdlMTyfV@Zi8Ts9mtrOZqslO7Ww6O8lMVbI/TqXmp/wBzsfWVmor/R/0nnMuAIISKdmdpGpqayERuLgf55577r3nnnM/Drq6N/rpTxN4sceONR9ajs98w/NZ3zVPDVdmd@bstm56RS0vCBhr1x1Ox4btezUhwVTGLN0eTvWhwQam5RtulnmGwbqG5ZxBuMbY9tSeeka/CW95xmzjjB3YPbMPEJjvnBi2@dpwIazA2F3DejN@47OeMx7rdt9jE9e0fQotMvZYh5fBtHfC9K7nu3rPNx0bgkqMPbMtfdzt64yiT1yDJyozANU7oTTLIRXGHjquZ0AOTs/wPAc9q@Cpu6bzYPfRx5fiqzn2sQ5ITSxjdil7VWXPTcPtX06hsc@O7t277Jtnn0qOze5dRUktsN2p7xz4l@EX2e7QsHWmyVVZuxxYAmL6hlXJVXJLQRB2z3ShFvWgtlhPt6FWsM62mDGe@HMm8XrWLSuqQ4/pHpt6U92iePZ03DXcMKLn665v2kN2Zvoj5o9ML0pHsb2J3jOkvmGZY9M3@swyIZEzCKAAaLvPToz5meNC1QYwHduaQ0KjZw5MTBLiAQDxSvkjg8MZ63OoTNuHRsB05gEalhFCSwsJiH/X6E6HzJn6k6nPALe@6eldC4B256xvDPSp5WdZF8KAmOR/NjLsoNECOBlAHDkcqy@mhJqxaNt6v89y0F4BjxODmUA1QqvG8nnwZ44LVINYIUYBMGq/vIzGDOoGqnzg1Fgxl4Pw/cgHsdUtzwmQWUYNA23ok1RnCPex6wxdfQzU6BtE088OHjOv57jwBj@My/vNdWB6us@2t1ly/9HdJGtG1SK7XSGqogY7hypIhIHsVLem0ELiNeFA/bhRagGrLLmRrLEkkEXLsUKBFaB7VphWBCKpuSo4oJ9reRV@JaZVWEGFnlJMZjGfgasPTcvgUIYIpYwNXCsyDe65AsurFR5z6FgDHq1HmZVZvsJKZVYusjLcq6yqQW4IusDUahF@JfgBtCqgosIvX@CAFu0e2im2tT020MemNQ@gE/geK6qsDBABXxUgaxWAAM98Hn95@BFay1cctj8Cao/0UwAvWeYJch0jYjxYhQo8lK0thTgfslaevTfC7IF0QLRihZUh@xJQogAoAGW1isYL4Y0MywqSjDxMQpiWc/ADrMtAgwpQPgd0zCEhy/CDd@BpGjAvDTiVBsxHU8FfA3cewUO8EoSVoBpLAa1GuncCGfF8tD4RHrg2gFGR0sioVCQQQICaYnmorxIrQCPIYyMo5hngDriUSwx4VUVllQKrlBnQsppjUC8q4IUtRAUeqQI@KgKDuleh8lXASQVKqwBUzReZECO0msdwSJuHtEAWtQBpCuCGSlNL@IN00CpUyFKFPDWtumiAgJtWhPIW89QytRLUbBnCgG4a4KpBU9IAW60C4Zi2AjSsYMMtJ7OcEDrSAWoEmzq0QSBGEfAhuBAX3Fo5z@mnW5OR3jV8s8dTdgeYtIRdoIRkhKQ5LB48C0hNQCUHYLAHAPoa1H4eyJGHqs0XMPsLATovH5LjrA84xHPs9sjIkFkDo3KIDS/aY8oOWU0aOOMy1wQ2ZkG7hKGipyNLww5uEIMK4Zi@zCATGD8N5xTHe@IyS9l4xIm6Lg7vMGz0DddlGBdkAi9LPMubdj3j1RQHpgVeA2CCBvDKgW5aEQLUMXWfOCo8kx7kN19Ge@A6Y@q9Y@RJluNM1vB/4IBnCOi@c2YsUF8wSH0ysWAYAn@Dj4KAzJlOggpJNfFcOUKQCNP1RiYApKyAfZuu0SPaB0WH1Hlg9Mso1pjWvJVHKHdi41OeTRzg3R6msaeWVYOBw@ixfFPpG6cK@vAxbHnsQhzCUQ3GpgBEVwchAzEnLCJItzSZxsujsGY9Z7xcNM6wDqKij0wcaawzfQ61NwBeZcz0MYhCDOUNG0bHMbQYXoNYEyDsYbEOWN@xk34E5cwFqQAKHZWEJA@kiW@ODRAbHUiCNV4gpJFdEmbdOTRlolZBJjmRY3KJULJwmVDcoxDz4J0Fxs/@tIdUw7xNm1oQjDseCk2uofe5n@C77PhYh58LA@QkEI1ldGDEp4haTIKD0dUA6geiTI8g4qBv2B7IY57MTBRcoeUPnQE0tjMTyg6iEiRdwO4REZAEkddM7skCkRwb0PjEYibrTSYM/EEAgeZ5L1eBMd35wmSvIdAagUzWm7runM0mUBPmGGL5PWcwgNb72piMAAQb91lv3oPuCZWMrUfoO8SRepPlYi7eNg2IY6OUt/f4a2xoANlBAhigWI9NflGAyYSKQKTQbS4d2DpQCovQm8yJLAAmSjFwHBn9@47hUWNx3JOo62NmnjGkrgH9bLBgRmOUdqCV2iSl9YHzBN0L4WOGwsrCYFZBK/jYsKHr9KBVQqeH6sM63WUD0E5iMgEKbnqvZ0z8oJ04xM5MOyZAHd5DAYp8pQCY7I2Ezdts@1KrgahRy4kJByhQIuqTQK7TkdcGKhCIC7axkOE5Z7HmV7KHGKeXchdfYpwlDF6Ka3CYUJdAaZKYxNRHVoLc0eyNkBf6yG1IgIHe5k6vFh/84tm7YyYNorwRGxXYjiArkRfisR6GBD/rKiB5YiGs5pIHRl3yuAG07o1XQHYiJK1@3FdWdBmY4k1Ax47trIAKxIzgYpTlEKoLaoxPkWvoVtQYqbt4S3WEDHuhleNABmPoZOK40DM405mTakZVFmtdgUaTisaKNGj0y0MrDBlJHPB9HAUhwcQCPY66GPZUEFV14BTAxLjGATzP4TnGEKZeT7AC/M6I9fPGBGOpbRso7erunAOB4sHwDBnNmem6wAZPcZDgY1A4mMjUTmFMAN0LOSuSg/r95cxlbNF70645u6zW9NBT/sITTnWXDVCjcUHogE6USg68ZLpO/pQyFiQqzsRXKCm/ixCRIslQ5akBKEkwSNwDRvN0bvdS4lIXE7NMnPqDipgGBybkMhr7RJ/4l7H7Avyw0YxPoF/TW50NYfiWJLhL6EeYYIAiY4DugpwBnRBE92q139XZG@AeoJ7P9ig1Cpn0VOVClJdh96O8AkIgLvHyyjwLz@2RQ4qNalgCjE4lp0FiiYDvSQlKKIKHogRjK3qQtMfDSK7hnlObJjBYiosiaXYeCfswAKQIGROED7Nn@p1AXLl1KxRcNhoNaGwgTQHb7KfjakI40yMDp4bIMkkjQSay7zz1sW@k0lBejHzBsQGxCVpqo8nO/ZELPY7eLwSIBGQVbGzJIWGDen5knkz7lyvaRk@MJGKvA6HJ7PliXYDBn/eGxnVUTS5RFVSJJFIVGy@mJ9BXGi/5YoWKQTTX8FD8bQSoxGo4hRgEbXUliXjSwG/RoPfmPSsQCbgLOjvnRl1A/ySYGYgYUTaQCcJOe6WnciDYHTgc9nj36H4j6Is8UOmadm3Jw3J6ukXemxhdDNM@OLjzZPfJ1zorYFhmt3bZQzELlRIOtdOZNLSnSkHWaptxGAvAdzvXw8aEy3FEIQhmkjOLiUrzHgwus5Cch08@vUwSkISQHJQDuPF3SaThcUDoErq6N7o0CLNhJgNZRknCuEw6YCHMyIGoY7ge4vN4@vo1Vt5lpCaBP2JmTXUOIPRUDuwwnYyBlwSwMKg74CMipQUp1LRxhnbhiscM8fkYpebLyJAoHWsyHx/e23/SILDBZIVEURTPB1lKd/sytHlr2jeEVXGA/YGrxzLyAnGUpwnXlQTu9ZYIvKhbtgY@AEBdR3aYZI3DonkjwH3vctnIV@pFLYDeCcJluTIuD/U@FNEYHjjE9VDlXTWKUsBisIq8Vo5YUejysNUrFo1yoRoftnqLPPtxoDTLCuNAKDe6EHTiSegjL6TIQKwO0H/64AriHgmRoApIIWaexWTKy7ME1F4kkyU9ZQ80NMcy5OfE8UQmphUlGU60yj2PlM9Y/P2Z6adyaf5U0xAXct/dPdDuhpGDOUCaySClAXVxHJncAS6M9DxoI7ZjOUOHbUEaLh2GGYLYtLaYu0PHvlJDOnpiURO4tgL8Fydu9AmMNeZrUhwpVVxd5as0uu2dAZdWS3kkElGIQCkUX/5CP9WBXItyPz34@j4MImoxl4vcObqABLE0RC509WK@5MEkyEgO8FlZwGid5UpvDwOk2EIHFjpgdFHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv5KlD5xrlD8C2d@qWmBD29a4IiR7ODR4wcHj/Yf7n5@7GvF4tJ7IVctAeEgvy7IQvKI0w176xbvmlgsBJeAvuFi9wIuMAUFJZx@n3ouMG4Zo8gcgTWthq9QpT5xRnbSS18uzBmGSl/YPd6EHmLn41GDhKBo9y1URly@zIfjObafke9PvJqiQC8fTbsyKK3KFz3H0ocKpYOBwbIUFVWXg0Oc1/BWpQBkvLnBU/DJLRAd5jSDqFtjB5QXWixE1sBSHDzNWlnmcAS6MK4oGm5ajlowlUbpg4YAurISlY0YML0BbYNnWE8ib9pfUbUKb9dqTisoYhhtqftD3I2BAapTCkYrIEX60is7vnV8i82BSyOky0ASTN6iSQ6P4VhgMRAkadYU9fyQOMQtcL4UeQXR6NUUZ3OBSynFXKGslooKqGWgpoHMKuGcmzTW/d5I8h0J4EnOgOYNYq1w4PV0eyBvBY4QWZD7PoKi5lsvjo/tNgjox7cIN1zIa83bLbWdrrOrSbaC@Ok6tN6l4mHbDT2g7ZITmiY92Rp@1tevsrO@Tr2rzxR/PAnGHGnCHu6CIPXaAX7dN@J9DxMo8UBlaymugpHfKismhCxMKuANKaVAh4KRFpqegnhJIPSieAgtB/hWLAFbzGbwcvCF8RgfQaUb273pJD2a@Ue5BmdLvQkQkSabe8ilPZwf9GF0jFo@cmmoXGTS7MxI4jy67vHZSkgULJqG6UFXiyDQrHw0I21Hy8HQCCgVqefAOaBd4bTpaDHLiEo/tDTIkHDCyQeQIGxaPRgCn4HEvCC7vCA8J/JZLtKJ7ZzZCK1rsIrUNX0@2e9MXVw8NPvxskH0vMbjADQqXIyv0ypj1@jxWVaemEoBSqDOxsbYwakEkK6IFRhUBJ2vUKIu6OGMNXSrnITLMABfYrf3gIv1DD5fJI1RiYImtc@SvqvsSl9XdOk1tOZrZCss/G58iZ0q/SgkwPJ6Mc2SBDOgJJ04Y4r0nOZbMPBOKO4Kk7k/ghJDCxP1hjMx7Ms6H9cIU@k6resmk8DwTTt1ntzY2EjWks1kFlw74NpG1w66MuDaIZdELowno4tSZMmFoS1KgX7t5EUrhDxLt7ENzFByeG1OUnqrVsu3s3pLDZ4aPtNQFUB5iC3hA@Ak040GOtNpsXmGazYgv8fKvodt52nPNScBCT4BgYC/BzTIExFAvUdp3jXqqJteT5FxwwWl0UARM@Umj1u54/bx@XE/c3yRzGLqdF1vgH4IzMtPjeWh60wnILi1CjUJeFu6la@1691GMpfcSqUqkgUZ6en0R5V0Rue0TiUNaFOp4@MkkDSgTqs3cgneLKul0xGhAI@BCVqGZaWS8nkF8u@m2@lMEtKmk1lgy41kEujSQyJ4VGicEeCN6J45A1JCx4QhLr6mQAySFqewu37dmIzmbjxCNOsGUjbOoC8W/3GPBHLxOJd8zdPHBbolTT@Ue3k8EG5x8g7lpcmcc3eBY3qsLG1dCcfdU2kwdnxd@UwGpUmODZfJjaQiSTASUgiHRMV@aHrYhXXbcKZefKZx5QQo5g6@R6MpMMtwX08WWpU5EYzeyGHJzdsAnUXrPTiU4NKVxBfAQgD9ngw/ZKIoleBiCUgXtEPDBL5Ie1toVkYlJDjrCefmi6XJKznKrU5pWA4zMoe24xoSkARSCLQdhTYzCU0W7Ig5oJmvK@sSQSgNaah4mwZwxHuWoxNtObuOrQdNxrH0oJ9DkidGX7CAfwyAPcq8Llyjr2wJtErruCMYIaA0yIm1qLbGQYDieJO@7M8gqZDCATceyLU7EDrPWF/TtFKvOKiFYdgqgNgjqCTUSm1QccMgSYXAdFDJ@3xaKNTRHx3e3edzJzTY4vCK82idsdOfglwZ6E1PDHuYZfvQnkzbGZtAhjD96xPrieP4XMuHl3UzM1xpNsdTS6c5n8vTMtem6zldx6KpoOuSLuJPXU@3dD4JFYbufvYQZP1nR08bci0WSdFPx9fmjfOQq7Pl9DyIrznSemu4POTxhiluFkUct8LtcshmgoASBkyDzXJQR6F/Gf3DLoVrKIF/Bf3HuFEOZOVgFoFeI88gYpUi4uY53EEUeJ6ruQv0X6uDRfFUiscFxwW256pG/qf@YLDknSfvEwlZk7XwLpA330S3pCPGUSrySLijbilOHFCJ4kQb6y7HC5hXtNdgZFjhCuITEExwlQzGdgvFJ9BNUBLne98MEKQnuBhCHBqX2FgPZE3vyrQF9KmJxGMLiQ3qJzCGKSi5CJsKC6a469RTbCdYmvQ493RAtafZk@0mX8xG1cnlWpvCJ983OwBiu1kPNyqti4Y5JZNRNIJKuEEKKiat318parQbw6M5dYGS1AVPAa1hpuWk41l5v/0mqXhEhgETj49nH@W0z0H9wF1mm7eUoVHHDNfRqx6GJANRtTtnEgh2GIvPT/dGwE5YZrZMSqifqT1wrL7EF8OgXTCuRmEFBXsRot1vwSZHw3TDjW@085AnRTYa2zN3Be6lKm1ejRDbZRcBgl5yzt6cZE/fsBaMbKeyN7FMv80uZN/pjJAk/tS1L@/H46Km6@pzTwi2sjTY7pOPP2vl2hyCMNZxgavCa3EWbusE@RjkIdxnCy7ckOObPg34tOHAxPKqMiA1o7UQQB9g8AzqLMooKBGi/sZ4syjLwACFNGUg5t58nGVG@kIeWLrvGzZvc3yVcT25@XJQkE2Dst8J1hZqLEcLMCCAmhgGKNbZ06O7@0@eyNByvVRyHxdqatAd9d4I5JB1hQ4pGS98jX3UT7KPME0atXMBuhooGZ0gPTTqOjR6UDMgd2QRQ8NNgWca11h64E3LWpSQC2IBgXBbVc8nGkXAUkYaykTAaivxf2ZzjSrAswYtPkOUBHKnbtWAtmZantrmK9mD8YTEU4iS5DopDAuNzRQxtU01Ta3HNce4QgyKFMmGUIJWi0mvgelBZJG123W@1A9xUc9yh0hdUaSqoN2/DTWs@gZ4g@RCEILkjbfsRSsnVduZzVWgaA9ZsHGXlz8GFyEsg/aMldlupqi/X@nIHAe@5McZ@TPSmi/tTq@xTe4Q@dQyRQ/3RRHToW1Uy9uhljdbQSdDVkIzLliQkCUkgm3VQZulcOL8oNpgMvJIpdl5RHQNSc7evCEask2NEQ3BpTJeGRehkgmM6YEDpXkQbKmOCwHUW4P9IthnjwUx1KaWF2QxhEvqyuklIVQ6FePpuBBo2icOLetErk5OVoso@EWpxyfW1ZQD0xvRbSlqhAOPq63Dzht3B3RbEYFWN4J1c/KgefNA5AVZUVee0IOm0FfkvLxXZCnbrjGY2kNaZEQ3k17dEFOqVijyoNs110UFIuD2r/C5IhowKWzPmlyQ1XCPNs64wHgEjIsrKYuiX95mxJboDqODD6mC53/5Rh/of7V2RjBQ4ARj5OjA0I01JQ3WVlaQFF/otrpi@Tz41DJ1Igy5bgLZ010okm5FjtWgaa1dkmD4H@PKQVDj0DbxBsLhNc2MY84X/sLn6kxWrZ3ZwDJ76@Je2nbFs6JVHtDf@kQELgSZBiUi1sUrwZjxlZaYJo1s7Gakwr1RjBozr/fR1J/yO8inN1aiOcHfdX0ziJkr6l3VAA1R75rGNVXu6ifTviNNToaRnFpaEXdRelrqlUAcCFZ9O@hcXXxeQNccwjgbPtdFWwxtyhk9bmoVnj31JlKXlO0@f6OOML4mB9fi93VRzOBwU@RYTzXTott7tsQAOjSUYNODgltKpRjRzEtktvTuHGWQ0Ye3smgDAXCcRi@TyeXXrCBPJuvTo8JI6avV1alnco/TY9VUgMK3rUp8sowKHGxkvaFWYbgyx7olaf2Ycy0zX7X/4ErUaOmS0hinuHBzurLmFtTHAak3tXR34bqmiS/wCFcL1k08B8PGY7PngDgwYWpZVrVw6IgNGMQywx1wi4xw1zDdYrsczFVk7INaiIO4FLlWswCn5@PO0DVt6j0YGt@RifteY41EdtZRquec4W@t@DAC1ZTfV49or1di9R7MSbJ6lg7j@NrhYGkOEOcYb2ioZ6Zn0G01YU9WIur3rJX@y10gnN2Lz9bd1Kw903I89pTu1xFo6AIV@H11g47T0tRtiea84@5reFC4lWFRobo1dKxSZajocFtb61N3gHw/eL4vh4s4lKrewKFC8cex1eC5lq@fKO7JTRVEB71c3MYac14zxK5iU8ESy/rSgWKA63OrS3YvV6GUssJn9NZkjCsrZ/o8fP4MQ8c60oZDx2RO4jRId5igWgGH73IR@2fJrXB9bv33Y0pXwJZvKkSsck8sAwYrul@pUqbl1A9MoeZy78@iBtbUmBorFY3D7hcGHju@Rsl4f6RyQTE2gwl5XAPAEyhRrNeBZvheWOM4jW/XMhPdMnvGzaLMMlObgPQ9QdX5MTgeo@NqiqE9nSzV6pJ2Zj@5nmSjSdilnf4SdhjyoXyocoOktCSfewb9rtWYuIaH@8AahVwuFwgwsYWVpZfrNKl8lPYLk9@XMiafRc6LuLiY5sacq/MgssR3Gq5lQdo6xZ4iV6uKbdqGP8f7e3LTruNYH1JTwFT7JopiIFnSjtrrauyKuBOcFWGLqQsPJzy6g3WTFny0CXRLoA8qzddVenzl571qU8K1zTGuOy2/Xj99E1tHuikXPK@Nc0J8j621XpYMZkNUuSKXr@11XEJ1uoal88esVLgOXlXOXwtvmWkEa7K4hstXbhcr7olLTGkyB2KZfdBSRsbYoNdrpHy9j6YFgsfaSDMHf@uCZ4bRU2b7Rm9dhIkJfMHG@9JScUxY8h0b9Csft/OhnmLhhtHAdx0HDhf3VhL5YKwPDW7T4jpOuZiwwE0zXK1bOFdPXdT4RpkeJFsYMVjfJKBTnRhzL3yuBPhw3oN6nY5vnm671Pl7OAf6Hr193U7Vq0OsPXJG9sgY8e3h0du6zgHt0ec2SK5DHbAejnDH2mSytJM9Tk/Lsaz3oSeyRs4oHWewEqd9POOKB7Q@CO5c70JA8Lhx8k73Oe9Ax9peMzKmMC55ju9MDIne1kW1cKKH39fx0HAt@medQbpWzweKhM@fFf6NuuVQd/zJhB6diTX16EZJJTqafJPcNOA7UGjvo@MO5dfOuCsHnnKwPYWWwFezmK7p90Z4Npy3bGPodHsj8yaku4bu2@aJEk758Nf30l2RMiaT7qK3bJlAXncuY3tpxMOf4uNgXaUHs0d8WIsc18grq2bo6PS1NNFPeh6fDUUXq@GEcKw38jPaNTrlXns1Nf0F0NiWpWh6ly9LoGMd7sEmibWSFR2FWLDhYPPE2lZKQjoK5JKRA4FHXZft8na2WBfL5/ltHULxUhJGse0nH0LuYIsPzQ6asXlb8F9qX0t7k1YOcvZoOvSuMkw@Xd8HEQ1v66ctaMtybMoaxizdDh7ryKxZCp5lhGcHZK6pce2aSvHaRRWKp1qS7pjw6MADqm66dg7NMicevzNpsHYpLtiyBLr45fVCTpv5amU6qJi@MeBLIOi6SUQcOy5uOAYZROrhSjrOoCMz54IXZ1y2MwSmLllsETmMu05sWbkbaHX1R2Om9PkjY6jjluoHpo97Mle0Cmqyq3YR3Qj7q1PdM786hZKta2xomIEvQ7rxE/z4tgLeQ31o9u4vVUSEZEDgYEMnfyw1f/S6WhdnI9PDHU2R45qJKWxyvBFjq@uA3rAi5uV5@8gmxaID8dOOK2Ovmlt3JnM8FDYn13XT6qZPs6zBc53quG6v17VInE3Hk6kXPFbjQHum4rPQ4xPy985MAC69AtbKRrrlr56pjk25ghQWDIoL5zpp/Oum5QzZ1ys5BkIbCGEonK9oOHdgeH6MG3Jce0VLpLzfc9kTJzoklxfsFdStkWeSaZv@9bM5vo@bc8InFoaPHHgQQXmAd/n2h0KQjlZT5MHNsv7iBPIN4zu0vKfO1O0Z6IzMisTVgiBXYy/cZIwHNxw0i3IW19J6jgXdCxzWyi7Tc@ypL7lT@9pRoXTtqFBjs0op1gxY6qv7D5@l462BNmXfJIUaoPxNPWu@cK3dMHCpkZk2CGLr@ehy7FCXuMvNIT2hHcE3pNlFm009Ytd3nVX6zuM5DCDvrTAB85@O7xo9XDa8Me9HzkPHdmA0mgCjHD8x@NH@pY0eqxNisgd4eB3o078xm6cEds0gxKUNfWJ0oX6thet9xiIO@K7u62uGIpobJP0vct3YVkyra7hf0KRfzL1OpV1G6L4xI91ifYPhfVDyez0uEuN83FIfWVqx8SaOY/M7cdscPNSH13MVGAro9v4L5TLut1@aF1ipny0X9fCU7xIx@tz2xLqyukbXsfj9mj1Jtsn3BOiuaXjKAzRlQH6lApNA@vKu5SHla3nIQjUCSfZU92iRfrWqsQCpzj5gC9BId3sOroQFjmt258TsD9zApqMt/HzjQBcIPwOOpfemgZHFm9Cyxt0x3dYqDLHafGJ08fBPl4x2@PrsamXymaHAYkFsR1d0zj9kV9ipSyz1GLSR9M3D1pIetUxVc0I34tRrl8tps45km0bvtY6zZg7RazE3vRQOZVYekXPNXHWsG9EssqLTgfaVPWl56xoINJYh@SMXdH7Fv256O7SmsmI9ZDo2cJF5eRVmrejqeCMqrLN6PT1irq4hBSb9gJdE5v24fCjtrpU8ETz8H975RIFBuFMqhBZGgHXdvIIPyE9dO3i8Twt87Hj@wJwdAt54CmAdO8FiFSEJPHjPQNfWukJA7dlTi88@DGP7rsZ9Uscksl4rSRaxa9@QDPtUIntvs6slcvjZLmUXrZ76Rl8KzB3gSoP0IDzmFUULnisWUOO8ETd7qgon7KxUCLZ/riLuWcgZQN5yfGni0VOZeI8PHhweyRNPXTk@7Y7wdMQVOW7JfoJWycWmpL7Q3dh6J9@O1jc9X7nzVJX2HhzIGGENvfmKhgQPXJlbeqyd9wzMiuqKvlYLwlDDXy0g3j96@CCzOInJUnsj1xkb6Xjw3tOnWTxp8snTlcHx1Pegdwyc2drkB/uqml7RfJ/ZtDq4jnuuyGkdpCMDtFFojPe5@ZUbhaueMzH6R/OJ8RkMnsjBvffMvrS2kI/0U3OIvZBV1xKKOiqryqVCOrYzG5Rtw42e6@rzxJwgt@zRQ@GPtdtRUHLIK25@tfRw3Yr/ZSmG5YKdCB@WSM1dba2@KUHPGI7Qpeje3xcxVVXX0fmpPoB6ZcW1lbUcYdX6sOWcvsdSshEoL1LkJfnQqiTzxn3kZWkMrFvBG07PB57g7K7dBnMdgMi7tLLDnxn2XLclWsu6TryoQWrc1HZtlK8b77EgFe3wOUVDzyvX@KIt9SzVI2f6hoyP3FiSvb07BzcleBLQ8vpYHz96xh7rHtoauT5iHGPjPTBeSEZfSDhvhYbu1i6n9l0ApV0LbzhZ3Z9r7Knu9h17Prt5EY6OmuLQTjaEI1j4RpEMy5yZq8aqHp/Xerx6m9FNefNDHM58SQ6O26AJAL379r9Q1VyOLAzhU83x1xtqJuzgLIUufY5m6@JBRwcRa@ih3CKDR3qlNvrAmOF2FD4bvEqpXzm@la4Z@8rp9cPJdWGVa8IK1@R3JQw9WV7OqdcALF4TxopyFPzAsc5Gjrynu4a3Yv/xSoSuK0j1moJUY9z5dSWHk6C0sBi414v4eHQheKxsrUeG7xYmI6drFlaWYXeAtiTZQ7SJfjU82E6hu7S9ZegERz74@@r8zqbGyowe6q9XBxCnOVkZBEzQGE3pSMTV4OUF0i7IvIY9NLkZRXbH8ffpbSWSjx3csb4yy7vm5O50sh5RYIloxf8yF1@K@BxUZefMY3fwRNxCOl@h8uO2uNX@60RZFs0HohHR@0e7YaM6fKposRwXWHz@eMkbz4z6h09jfq4xm63TdaXZOtVxZcgi10dHhaVst5svTlcQa/0xI5AygA1Hz7XiD@dxnzy9yglQaxv5YysM@US3FxOlSxXWd3w6YLgy8PF8RrsnV9b0iG9euxLGzzU@mdpx09deNjBews8B89OXnhzaJ0@l7EwmnV7@ukb8KCkaiE1tooHETTo2CnHfvGEbwVFNCBDDw5/B4VS0owaqo4GnSwUC4Tc2IZtGQy1W2Q5@0qIGgmGackQvslYV5tVim@fBuctaTb1gGw0m1kQWnHyNjM9yA6oAF00/QpmYdKKyTR9CNsNTm4y@BcDeMFI2QbpVizl4k5X4@fV6cK4VUNo8f3zweP/p0e7Rs6etXPsiOPcaFsK2IbfwdP1H@b4IZQ/IBoMYN6dM560tyI6@U4BKqheWi0HJLhWtsVS0RaHEHUyzeW7bikJHfxXpAvCTRJ4bhYJEil4cdlhiqp/g1HeNn8Klw8RQRRy0SHlCndVYblXGEx0Y8qYdhF/@9gqF4rd5avh1Hsw4sIALDXHoOP0gR89gN19hjvd2Dx48e7LPQgQXjebM7PujRrXIDSRzcwRQTwOT9kI1WDJIkoS6ajSS95JAmKScZDU6rE3GiaGdQ7SQOnjMO0i9xVKbBB8omIwqRfkv31AukjJu601D3GSIVBKyhSZPDWVjY4MdQSNhd58cfLb/hCH@@3fJG0mEINgRnhT9sx/1uXn/0GBL@F0id0xslAxjCPHT4uER6sUpb6Q5dd3J@q8TkTl9Oksd2fGPPkQiCPSZB2i3Z2Rr7ZIdrjSZxuFfUwrMpIUZURMKTYLjDDKaPHM9dmp6Jp7kRhwGaIFsubHjphOyuiezXfz0En7gSadvTQDqU9vnVn4CmyAJaGlyxHKybJOQ5V@mEGMRk9sb0Ni7BgyszLNBLTf8GvsCWiLO0tb4SX9JaiavJAlB18glIVeORbxissxTjl3l3a/8M2VYZ@D2wf2dwD3L3YG3XwreBuD@Ze5@oWBDu2ribIFLHCE0SxiUgCMS0R9pH/vilM2tKywIh5bYQr7KzDFU0ylRHaPzHPhdAna8gJNqfQaVBs0NaiywqsDzM9x2Cu0i1hQFmxQKezLtaTdmfIPZJfuIpWKpoCqApHQaAiSD5kM8OcsBptM16CbCqTlpvARJYnt7m4mo8RmNUp3XrLJpv8iLLyNENyGucDZC5FoM0kCSRQoIawbJYPDJqGlMitwrqSaRcfUdGJUoHEcvfLcDQogsBcTiNDLQQvYMP07mu/PQzmcXP@cV@9jFZgBIUmFMIldaFAJ7BI8cH5oPdNLF52y4PQLcYMlHQDSg5/FP85F5TWyP8tWetThGG35VI@hrMvIADiqfuzyYxutWfI4gniKImriq@bZesGP/2G4rvG0yaKY/WNGYbXD/ojJc02Z5uXevGldMXTaNiMRit5/aDqq296AwLKUpWl5RS@lFkQqFlUUKShRkA8VB0y5vIDtgU8Ayeob5hTPxdvf2Dz45fPz0igFBipm8HA34fnM7cyzJ2VY7ciTjxVqukjv3lKcP79wLK2KBdCnGjYHxByVRryvJYsYKQS5OQFwu2ioML5duPcbP@Rnpy/jmtetQo0RX8FBzH5Av7UKW7tFZosuZa5VV1CoWr0NpAU@Jgd7jB0GvoJpKn1@02tvNYzuRvNoSVnSEFwl5CzsBuI69rU0FG/vVwmHBoo9mHuFXtbx4X8yv7oviZh7tWOE5dN85WVjwCjxiAbHyhtkAixRkJYy6tvcdchl9YWdO4x/15Bav4vZ8YgiXctdRPAbqKPw@KHKRhZXMwEDkCHQjy@wKoR0lbigytGcX2YjkNpBSaSH41gLPOBV8MXRWm8m05SiVRm5HsLLsOpuTIby0AB0apbvHU9DJHjsTbnublpbvGqHriQPsFzRm0kkN9sl0DPEG9Hhi0DQ/cG4JEgMlkxGqXJYCLhGYnJxl0Kgn5NdCw5NBweVxv5iapeWRMeubQ@DtqXQWONpHqtpmkVlKLDSZobSTItXZohau7Yof4/HeONk/yDbpbIGA3tJl0HmNWSp5lkzX2pA/@ifPnp8m0@KqtkQ2UgOjof3LxlIj9Mvq9ZxE94PeGVoiXcUtqtWrXAL8LgPm1rzCD/9Uq/LIE@hDbg2U3J/67gNwghiRGoz1CUtNbW4JTWb0mjpO2VkyESU1uTFFm2UypFDBgwJkRikH5OLjd0q35yylNKARoK9n9/Hx2pywlirLbXBTJmm2iR/k2gOJC00ApgXQgSFJjcA2sAmBmgEY8U4i8wYOaTAc4sKD7MmtCKbvE9FsqIM0oVKz5i0W@8DasuQoVqu1oEKXuWKVQeu7yg5lBcBe4XOhXA/UDYykAM1A/ZWFxIKRX@V4Cco3wRG5H1hXAXQSMQOoodEVBrAW5kl7Ixd/qX0b@grIB7Xas6N7nUpaEVlkpWXomn2crec2vCMVL/jqCnRTZSlqss41uo8xGdrD63AzMGiW7R51GPESS03EyXD5O8iLtqmq17b6IGFQCxCzgANAcJqtE4JDw4/hvokVYauZ/U9/il9aFlObqnrScU8zyWKuDje1XmRF9tHmsSRttnKN25s6aFH@q9kx6OTKVuHuqTEadA@GyrEosjwrKMrW@Xny3tZj84VWejW7yKuVVycTtdSSX83aYqWRPWmzx48/f9t5mxZnp/NX4nFKoy8B7x2@EdUCKvqJWpWd75TyiZMqflST6XrxhM1Ab2Un7DVcJwOG/@R@3Y@5dXR3B6/pY0RJkSWOj/ELymJZVJRWsg3/pO6/hIsr/q2m3JR32m/fplu67s/mzDTNidfvw88ZgQSppZ8yyPcWcHqKr7BjepICRdd4NljMI@hFuDU1PNoo3@6gD5lWnO0aw@F0X5@b03v@w68/D69neL1@smJCop3JpCSpddm71tGLCabltD/78cZF9vxxZ/vPvjlWjA18HOLjOxcP0f1ULX60sfHRnTuFQlbTNO5@/PXHX9vd3S3czRYft4o7BSm3sf2nf7KxoWnbmrLR9jy1nWydnHwuarmCKP/ZD5Odx4@/6nnN/P/5jbdNFW9luJ2yMvAJuPJMBSfeK/BTUcZ63yvxOgGtXE3M6a@TCP3PN5ja3Cn/1@8dvkr4iaamPHfh6SdeJUqVBHeCA97y4dtpopnYxmili8RcaTQa4Cz/138H6ZufABwMmW/DrVkMYZXmiabUoCRvEs0SOFRNg3z/7298I4YhZxMNEuPC6zZrwSUWypq404Zri65tAa3fSTlFCePZ/sg3HKZWbqm38MWEF3jYBloLN/zjBH6ilh3eZuxJK5PJtOWOBJf8AueIFFXVjlX1FnAD6aOtRkPaYty8Xz5fvIWWiNM0ozV0YMA0brHn/xhXYpVn/WcG90RIlDZuv7zbbEKh8s38VjNDV9CTqFOVK6Lj3BZZlr1MggrSar98wHsOa4q5iiZms1nenWZIKmm2aEn0UfsEvyIf7LLsst9SEogS@CY@PF5iH68//9/@/Pt//j36@z79/iOaB7T75kDZgkin0CWacN2u1XrNpth0xfNjfG9CO8rVKrWK0rk4Tm0BB2o/YWru4zfJYj75lFFXUhk7TlNquCjbZpA9vjcTC@8m92nG/YIAHpk8WFAKcixRjdwR1a7Eg6E12EgptU6bbQkFoobUUkvFtsRThVg2q6x1G6pJ1MpVsd3UitohVJ0q8oobbXrMSYBmWArpGODbXJStGYUs3ppxr0QzTNZcxPnQeCG6TSHRailtgwaE0I/d3qhtVGqlmqZ0Is@rF6tf9TIM47GXOE1EF6dOYkHQRNQ0L/uFVRG9sLAFsw@JJyQkg/0DXwm2A9cG/NE/XNEr3jfIJ/CmKFevDVZTt7S8UvyotK99YPYCjBOs1@12X/e6KAboXb2nq74@1Wf6XPe70@6sCzIUm8IPYs6i67oiCYm3rQ32hHOhNsuE13HmxuuZLHcCJzkc/EmSM0sIiX@Eq6lqKtuC8SkHNxDKyAk6M/6pqsAS53C132613m5BB21mtok7tptSgCU85M7tdka6uGiBu14P/rebkbNOF3dB4doXmcz2iyaIHi@arQyAfBGAlDlMudNsb1NAlFeQWRC83QbZRcpst7Ybzh79IAlcUrLgJEvO7TbA3V7C9fbtjAyu2wCguQndMZ3JbErSBg6NrWCogMjtZiYsFOKQAmHh/Pxn/IGeBz32YvuiedHavrjY3ob/bbpfBE/wvdi@8k@PxbUmziK8jZzluKU0j5XjgE@04V1WmugjK8fgaMIT4rXyWqXdQgdccvu/zX85u7hHPohyWwashcQW20qgrbp8YktIvHz35f@Cv@N3X/4@iosM/oyakDjHXq1sobJZ5Ton3Jj90GYP@WWDG3/hK/qgx8Mmetr8ZuN6lKK8lFmNT/mn1EopLeP423EGHTz@LrOXEBXlNhiWmKhVSmIno841ltgWS2UamH7@ypVMJv/JS61aTvLZGTy1/dLzvIcx3BbYQeS6llMl9U2TGybnn4r4@VXXP/n5dZeQeFNlRg2o0vMYp4eQgOaTkCQYpJrbY9zVi8sjEmqip43PpWe7Ek6d6D4tfvX4tEDjYL9RrTb5ys7mY@oqW3e34K7C//4GlEJIdF/h34PX@MeOevj35BX@saPX@PfExz/2sIt/R6/wb7eLf0dj/LvzCv8e@vj3bIh/xz@Xz6t1cfOcCJBRq@rF5kwkQtQTO83jn/Pdec0y7JbZb/PpI5bKF6osnTj@OWOGX92u8eobJH/y3W9@M9loJKUkfcWioDouU9N1IDKg7iXrt5NCosE21U01Z@V6ObWrdsFhspzLcqPcSO2D3NRRWc5guXluznJjR@2Dy4C/HLjM3IDlhixn52yICKHg8js5H10DeAzhbwCAXPgzcTdaV831GGRkoapCH8BD8OB60zkWWizJxJcG6JGyKufkktnGz4a0xJcvj5WttlatMBnbjtxpvTxOttHAtFYtsO7c2Dh@yRIeKKL1hHJ8rAQ00QpEsouLTmf/0d1OR8Hh5Pihc7j4Pzwcx1@v/R8fOg8PnbED/4eHh9AHjGbmdgY47e3bDeC8wWMn0azvHNeIf4c8PKFs7xw38xK6Sxlgyxr6ZT7wWkCEZ3PjWEiepVCHOEM1ov78rH5aJ/dZ@AqOTn0RIYzGHcETrjMYqkK14gyu0zN00Bs6z54fRy7uUJ6fgddzBgpU9A@KWvz1H@Df/G/r/@EzlmapVjudOr/YTtGVxr90@vzi/CK4N9OpVPCS2oY/9IB3THJ@0UQnRToHVyuVbqcvLrgf3FPpbQ6wCdlsNyntIh7w90SUJWXLb6l/2CdkHVzHyTrTF5thjo9nuVy63g3t4uPSrv6Gdhyk6/Tts81uS23/6Q/p2wc7aYpULNTr6hbjL1pBq9cL4Vu5Uq9XwpfNVKp69WrmdtQSKA2FQjpdr8PLTgg2B68R2AqADV@KANXw9F7AKc8PDumrAMAlign8HEfAKnP0TRH8PFVSrIm3bqWCz17v7KZv3dKquTdvIp/JBLzUJa9Op2@6nQ7659@8ETsi7U2pFuE9V3nzRs1VM2oy7bipR/hdM8gqJansI61JuVaB/WqFcvofRo8AYMXt7VKh2SwVwF2q4Cr51YuowcTNZOI8HNXLac4ak5uKWOdqKfRuHBI8dn6RoGpnhWI6Bcw1DfLdRQL/uLdarXL/NCuUUpVMNfhrbIB2DdIK/0ORK58pbJW3boPwin@zlRfy5Pq50VAvGudGDWfHL@q94KuyeBrfuHUrXwWyVnL1Y6HTubt7tNvpNERRRIkHbuhJ3F1AIwVuskU1Xqy2W1jAdq1@m5qGWikyaAM8jpSEEYJVoKIUbauoVpAWgjlAYxtQfkElqm2wDUGjJ96EKqflBniCWoKZ468PF@uzLhvixYY408lMZtHFLMbD6d7rRZEcfgWh0SulxSvyMaJLSDx@sLu3f5TVtiWW0O7t7mW1p8/uJFR8LS7eKTiP70/2d@8ePoMEjx/s7z7d//jgs/1nj8HfY2eLK@T0wX3xjLtWvJ@x58IX7mvdMHRjahids@n07BX7wjQ7JtSgNYVCOEOXeUYHcJ/oi3LU4dczPf2LL3R3Qhd794Nvv/vBf/fud7777ne@/e53vv@TL7//bfj9CH7f5c/v/ttqEe8/@fJf/O673/4d8PyP8Psj@P34J1/@@jf4j97/GH7/Oeb3x8EvFo//BID1Sz/58ns//MmXv/wb8PtXwe83rv5@5cerf9//1vofpvve714f57v/Dn6/x2GFcb/729wPn1fi/zaP98u/8e7X/j3//9PgD52/8@7X/hhvwcs//40//c/vvvkfNK3yp//m3be@9@5b33z3re@8@9Y/1d79@r9Rc/Hb7777/h/81R/@3l/94f9I/z@i@@@9z/@73/jnf/G//sX//hd/GPx@DL9/D64f/8V/gL7xt3/wA/z/3h/87R/9AP//53/9t3/wq3/7S/8TOX6TO/6ff/Vv@f2vf@U//c1vfeevfvyNv/nVH//Nb/7BX/0fv/x//fp/@uv//vf/@p99Ez1/88d/9Ue/9Jff/PZffutf/uU3v1xz//a19y/fw//LfwSf98fzfeC8T7k@1OfLnwmfvw81FrlAO4HW/Yvvfv0XoIH/GmPvvv0jPLwCvzX/P9JUivMj/vb/AYd2tcwYkgMX/H713be/iyT6H4BE8B/R6zvRy1IIf/nO4gXI@lsrEv3iT778lz@kt4RRa9KSCw7YFa2S2QKlZqtaDQbtYDUGkvzCMrQIQJDTd5BDLYV9B3nbux98490P/@m7H/zmux/8Eg6YUqGa3c1K6g0TpBCx@B7xMGLpfeJhxM8x/wxNkEmZz@GNfR4Efv7550LnjYKnpG6/Ad/PyYtfjAfhKaogKAxDfzxWxd6wuDtw5gLnZuAb5cxY6@XLNi6Wgh/mniGBYyuUh4p5NssEiM0Yn3NFf4g02yLnDO/ki8EzAW@L/4VzJrAMxgkmbzMLJzmCdEEW3CkUIZvMYqaXBDTGRaIt7kOLvJRvocqwBLNZZgaaLzgghwwE3cmwRqORwYQNjg@8ctSaFUaoZDINKDem5mmynQqCmN0hKJCykXnCOluNGU@YQXjNkBwZAb2eiKomZiqNu5BhY3aXISwETmBfvmw0K41ZE8G95fTIzDJ3CCcE1sjMmm/hvUEwIZ2QuPsWUKk0MplmBTPEQvLqyXZ4JRWpcFT2DMsEdQBP3Ku/c5uxj0S1Ina4lIgE47HxnlnExogQHcKPM1tBceg/dNJviwi@QVkFuTAevkMC6Q6XUTECwJUkWZYZ/HD1fIfdhuAZB5WhbOGR4RAy1CKoBUQeDCeAMkKG6jdDL5B/orH1wRcCw8Jsbm4KiaaYFw9lIp2iMPekRgcXcC8fqiA1JpaqInobdIojxAXS1yn/zSSuiiUZB8w@yvDf7dtb7CMoJj0XfgKTMnmn4CQ4lO1MRtQAftPJCC9AFxGgnRKgN4I8a5C6kxGyWcbkRgLD2OHhYYAEebxoCBlo5lpexXdcC5pOpwlIIctZOZsNnjI9yUMOHDKFBk95E4lLXwhmmlaog8pUZ@jF4vqNCqower59@xZqhTZH1Q5AS2XBPimtUKFA8ODGIixrHp720QpVgWvoTC0VGEvRVClcaZYWWIptpQW@pZ4jEV6ppFapJCkeUF9ObYXb5koqNQecJk00EdHw4mpjpZgOA/cO2d7hw4f7j44m7TYTDPrisdGZuE7P8LwUhu0@usuPU2jVUjrRaiHoo5qGDEbYr@WIGR/cfXLwtMZ4oYMqSBFidVoUDYpZVYXEZPJ8OxFsGxLxa16O@BTvtUXZUlo1D0kTTSHRM1CzwNXuOm0XqQsPveEdZwbKf1YUs2oJ1bk0TQ4z4WvOlKGtSW6YAvoUHrKQt7eJAkLzXKKFB3RCbZWEZjPYcMdUofl0/wgSHB0yVcvJQvNzNpMxQ@lCaFoNy7CH/mgTd66JxzkxVqbNVi6Lf1o@D3e1UMqqxXJ7Y8M6lzDPY6q2c9yCeAGv5xIW4ytwMeErAvsKeMEFeeC@QhZs6jw4rAc769CqU4pvrxPVInSztHAMFc3BCZPFBYhC615exhESG1//us@aTVCqpYN7QgK4xYiFm8sksy@PZKrm/tQ1KHTIWN/8zMTPtMl905tY@hy6DlAjcXFxMQBIB/eY1tTolafo4/2iRz5dcF/MdCFh12qNt2qhLGgntdrbvKYJ4CFsKbh7bQMaAG0C2FL4X92DTPL5igKcShVFeOTzeQEnhwWhZgiMdnq8zTUaEm@D@YJKGz0EtPyvzxpadAVxZx8t4uZzPC6GQAAb@i7LhWFlHha8lQR6A6Lh1jb6zmw96Jy5W7fyOHORL@SiKQoqMbuAutnMF/JIceH/v5YvWqDZnjTzOXVbmYBTB2dhW9HB2QVncVvpgtMEZ3VbMcE5bebV3LYybQpM2OYGHhnaj2iIvjFDe7LcT2x6hjWQ8YRQQ6QMNHE7MJjcDBM2@42@06OPQtf7sokf58ZjnzxBoSDWHRtNjzXQCAEdlGWp9LkwbJzR4VTBaAxltGbh2rol9OWu05/Lnj@38KyN5biNJMiFyTBgAd0AgQRnvnby@UKtxdryxJnsCFqxnGmpORhJ8KdWslp2w9gpl2t9uWcZurtTrBUr2T4e4wlWrXaKudpQ/vzhg/u@P3li0NmenUIVEqD9J7TUslOpFYvtVksUMy3Kpo3fuuV8StrYgM5t6H0JngPH9j1Jq7Qhcd90G41kcievapJay@cqF8KCcEhzLGFTwKQZLFkW6X4esIKa7djAdWpZPWueExVqg8HgYus8s3gR9HOJvwF9LiQ92z2PXutSLF6NTbOSuQgEH30A5D4PlutqolasiPVWffFeLon19oVwe2z0TR2P9Bznzq@mKgF35lATkNExEy5qruP4ta4xcFxjETGvlsKIHKGrEQriRZTdcQ5zPL@aXSkWaXZ@FUqhKF5EqUK0hIsLoDsnNvQLbryzSTtfW2q10N4HVtRqb4dmPbFuEi9e6HqzCZV8XihrhWKhqOVLpWJZgyGnWigVK9DNcqVcUdMAQKFaqZYvoEULCV2Xmo28lhc0TdLyUl6V1Dz@3@DQ8P/942vwr@EdUuU14QhtYzyCsQzGX5s9wDP2vsOOHPzKypDdMXprYuyNdNojvOc6nvf3iHNHt0940F2TG6SMgu7r@Kkpb2z6ozUxnk3GaFbDcP/RIOyPu4AgsiYe4Q7cXMtxVkUos2eP15TyYWQCGojBbUBD9CcHH98/ij2P9nf37gsldufw0d1Lj2IQqcge7N87il7LPDRMWoxAfG3/wYPLr8GjcPjsyWDquPgT7h0@KyxukRceQRUKcC1HirwJSHDDV5L2YJgH7ahYDh2qgAcXboHGeitwFksLZw6dz/n5WtOLNtLzo9Y14Sg8dKsz5Hpdg/W49RRUocmyWSBgq@WqIEyY7Zyxco71HcvS8bvZgw3wHOl4gNBAKdOiz75j1meOa/XPzL6xITzEs4pVFb9RjEgI9wHIeNojM0IgYaCdzD5@0RoXlbrW1GBT/Jr8Gk94oBc6XXM4gvHwzAkjCF1dZ/D70AvSG/HLv97D53mQ35UQ62p0ISGI4n3d128nKq261540c7XarVvqY1es5kVvaOzPoL2yZ9B/dHeerYi@LN5jcicxxJUGq6QWC86kqTdBNWiBIA2j6E5BM5qVXPGvf@tHf/cnv1rVGurWce7hg2IN@CKIlYwkx0C6lEnP0KqVYqWa1yrZSrVSKKqlYjGrallQ0cpVkNJzakUtVYpVNVspVEEaKFQhtFgtB7KpEgqjylYNwNo9/F7uNqkq8gh0Er6AyF6n9DRL6NH7lIkGpBEF1Ap9Ooi9ZTZgIGNqjuXLDCDqrMcS9@7t5e7dE8U7@IIbJ/ZyotjHl2IllyvfEUWDQvYqKNmIDk9TQctjos9fcrk7e6I45QDQaLcojvBlv4TzW6Jo4sve7r17mM8AXzRMD9FOeAh/scKXMkSz8QVEZgLwKoIG0XZ5PgVCdB9fMEsMucdD9iBMFD8O0cGQJzwaB3A/LOnurige8JfdXQzZo2IXOaKf4ssuXaLowgs0e1EcgmPoQocTxS44sfGLYg9cvbkOfvhtYrTrbPu6KM45eZBAojij2HrvRBQ7oT9m81mATRGpW6MXlZf6Nr1U8U8UtRBpjJaPXvKiWIheClC2@/c/00d@3xjya@7yZw9Kev9@Xjdn0/173Y8/7g6HXXe@u//xEwza27sPUsF86naH3SBhtwOXA6n27mv6yXh@@YJSH3Q6Nd1aGfRpp1PQ7UtBnXnHQAwh1SvALLiGmNG4swdBe/c7t/VVi7kEsIP9fgzPLl53xvC8o3d5UHhRED1n3a5Yx@aPIjuuwGJPPAEWamfHes916vg@a2wwlkwls/NWKdeuUwAbg@idq19g@CCFdx3nYdLn89askWs3Zo2yxjcCDVLi8UwrmmJ2Y7yjVou1DX1H1QqZWQ3NQDiDJEtK6g5Lqbe2XrPUo/SOBmK4eLyzI4kttb2jqZVaqfxiayqK6Rred/LlGkTMJXOM4S3dKrd3ysVYknI5oytarVxO1y@AHj4M5F2cH@mkUmeGfpJOI7qorUMRqKxsTuU064PULDtrcLzYPF2fNdQ6N2XKcldg9dFu9rTnOy6HOARws51cDZfAU6JarYiQv6Kk0mlUo0lPVoTFVsrnXz06OTr6HDghE5rBLMJj/pnvevD68f09@eAwfEN71/I9VH0cV95DdrUUws0xh15HoATI92HkBIUq9MPDdq5jyfu0SQ30pzAgtGIqB7Yn5aP7S3CejpwznjPaKqiTATO7ZzA0B272md5ogkvvsxRhxfT0GY3ZnWaz0WmM6Tg/FDFM9SkjW9kLMAcexz2yoEDJz/EAWhDQaeQu6t3GLDEDOJ0Gk9SXY6f/Usv06n20An6ncQcT1zvw7NaNhuG6jismxPpgx24wNrU9fWA8Nly0DXJwuAkSBJ5KSw2Ykd5kx/sYew9VhQup6TJ7gdmj6TgFsng3vewVe0XSpL4aFvmcjkniBomL@qDBUi/S9Vfw6m6yVF@@k94p1PupO6yTBp/cy8HLAdNYqVCnz/OmEBJ0IqINlllPN5qfgtDDAZ/UaoBIUMcnABNzArBmnwL09MS8qPcaFktJbMbSRJ5CfdhoYeo3eNuWRLEtSa03baEpSc@FJvTT@jyhN7xplz4dwXJdVcuV6jPwU8uF@ggqVn8xq7uNydQ16ha8BlNq/DSoXgdyAtUAzOs3qXe/8I30tlRscL86gXpjgZzRkTuNWd1GY3TQJBr5BgRkWoVcFtRnuJWzMMxrpaxayuazhaxURl8Y47PFLHiCSgPiRMpKiYyJ2dwsJ6tZ1VCzqdxLs/8ynT1JgZxCJGPprO/s29MxAx@oJGyV9ApPnaUz2pbFoBYcpm9L1EyBU9SxYEDzEZuY2RGCemLoFqVIpyWW30pZmymMs3k0ney32rXa/mzyVQhKSa92SplyLvM6na6nNtINz3glNOtCE7kKlXqyAW02mG1k3nTcgjoGl1rWaq1WF4tYzmXzuTyUzuy8GW6LTbGdzW2UVKiiC0biEeMcIz4Bh0LOwm/SQVHbMqDq1KpWF2SaDctXNKmqFLeKOT4jx1MKk4CtISVZ6lgMTz6nksmylkymk3VcC9gQg8lf4GXEx5LAVJO31B0R5C@xJlY1jLBgiXS4NRdiBxLYhYAzD6xQFRLnwsX5xTbowQrtnQRhkW2QS5Kbt4VEjTEQA48DW0vKBmMfuiUzs918wZ/HuKke4ApkNRakT9oqZZioe7HP8Bz/DksCYro7bmlavt3SyjCQAXMMo4IGXsfljwRu25ebQGHvHPDbzjTxCNynbD7XM1I4H3@LsWFmU6AyJy4vde42dodPdsONYLt7OMV7DMK1WE@KifNkInkBf0LiNp270/i5O5aInbzjU/w/l7ydSCaTOJcOhHqbIB7B9s7Dqa8afsQspdc4R2i1028fmdZ5JS/xGQlgURcXiU0FFzqDNYp8oZSuUk2F558@falBI0nYTugBShFOHsHgVSzivHVCeTnxvq5V8g8PDu277j2D8eNQlUJHbCZYTpXwVFG9FvgWxc7GiQptJC/mT7IJdjtBm9PFakUTNe5RT7ATKanW@BGqydPqi/KLyouHzw6fHd4TEscbbzYcXKJg0Ua6t/YnX4WIyXwhydhxIzFrFOrBNrpmU1K3NTR3VmY1YP8DtSTl3jR5M29SQEmDkHe/8BuF2XYF3rWcCu@aVsxozaa6pbF0YvLuy99HyzXn@5/tPmBJnNj@uz/5oVb@uz/517RHL3lBk91avpyAmOhUS@XE@fnk/PwCLh5WTLQTHKlCOQ1uvvCiJpqKquVt266zmqLrW@VMQbtt15UgrlpW0wlPSgRLSOViwnsTBGm5CgSFazzkJZawShL7T8yipt7e3oHi7OQLWn0DmpEaHd9k0d@24VUTQqLy8OUbxuCl1@wPh6ZGLkVhtbcS234rbbO3uL7yVtpgLxtNXKdX8dBnuP6whYfgcA0u2cwoW0kGahFrti7qF@0MLWGA6vjCMLbs40ud4HgDj0Ese23Z8GdsefSHiUIPD17DN2PrC09MbaUVpd@PzKNtG6zYhFaxpQBuW@EiBP@TpOP0u1/4dU0r/d2f/MqbzpvO5xooktVqSdUSP/3p9tSeeka/@VNIeI1JklAZpBUctB2CjkiJZNxcphmkihxyD/TXqY1SM48fqpSoRKLMYQ5to08qpXCKchJVZIdbxeunKNoWWizIktRNVqjSdUGIpFOSqt1hL0sw2BbaU4SeLpwLX8EgGIxZA5iw8JUFKPAYw/Dr9DqeNXUndGgkRenUdpbdgiSQw1fQ4OAGWVoIOLkE3E/ZupqUo@wR1UimYmPD89B8IQxCwlcgSWBr1pqziY5GQTCmacPQIWMUwpMC@i3Iuw15WzxBh3xTVHoeIcs4djyRDZK38BUQJogKJsgYzNyGCHVgS18BAkAZUgFgs822WT7Nzs1Mpr6wjXiBu@LReqMeGiQQMBlC66MBjDBxHeOBF0j8@HVDbBdBDYN4F/MMgXAYfD29AToDJqc3FNrIYsh7gwJYZJ0rRUVjt24tsGo0zH6aUYkQ/ok5wYkuqgd7Na4ALNS3PurXxCxDq5P10DdqdkDxDKELrU7i5ibrsaRMxNcLQYD/92602CIvVRUF1LEAQX3xXtEDkkFiJDuvwx7bbjBVK6dZhHwPcO8RUnQuPFIij2cfydrnYeAFYPjTRPjtEGBRR/HJw6DdXrZIwWAQneKHG9AuGWcGgSUJbnkMWd2BH6aOUkFRTItiD0wXFBxa6A@NHqbyahqTLYxEEh60110r4C5xrZjGB6XC2AyeOhrvC/LZIKNDPQcq1Js4Nln7I2tEuJ0fWgTwqMBQGkd7ap/hh36CuqHEcYw8MpKGLR8xJuuF9IVkSosr7V0XtOCQNllmDGXWG/eZVmUpamhk0M2OwKUpESHcBWkZady1jDGg9NQw6BSXV1OUIQhb0y5ZtXtoQrsa3TNhvLE9JfgYtXJmnpjKEX6oQHIGeNiL2whJoHyG3Y8v6gcW5CzHOWGWeWLwOeHUkoUVj4G@ACJvFii7@AFha7hbRMtnWQ6CszwW/MrwKHNnJRtLu5Gap68@8@pGqoM1@oYGH9PFD02f6naMvnS9EQIV2Zt7oY0msjQE73LEco3AOksjiXYXIrNDQmBtqkGGjmRca5ikQGENrTShU5i4xilDZVfAMQaYZi@0d4K9GEr7FRoAqO9Bz0Ljjb5bQys9gInbT/Wg6wUM3mYfsbwmYERuQiswdwUwsOoby9AhDJJiOTy/DxUj0wQ78hXoneM@hKF9iKD5YfqwdaObDGsumjfbCMDhoEN5NRjvFuFLMfaCvQPbMxV9AwJLgOEKTDZSYgbAZsS0yEFH6S8n561dIF5SY1chZRlCCEgNUEhUCL9Ez2Jf5BEg4I7ucbPtgWnHs7MzmeyNTl1TNjz8So3n2LqlTIYmSNSO4hvjSfA9UBO/Ax3AXbgk/nEqeTKa7MxQdG1Ub835UxAGXiPYc5NKDrwkDo6n@BGW4Zhsk6FRMI8a1D2TPuDUSwVbgHj709rZ87D91bD9SZXkBQJhDMHMsvNsLwvAst3eSXZw1q8HAafUIQE41KIReqIVYDd8GXuhy5wMohiOj3w0CupaJ7R6CpBEPqW7yJqXMIw5D1@D94k5g0S2ccZ2XVefpyg8jbGxAafmJPawOQz7FAJOGGbYOTdJa85a8/ZS8lmUHAa1aO@Ai4bHhPPrgXL7xBg@4@EzCJ/x8Nki0zDb1qzNRTL0usDiYKtHe5VhTAQzD@NccFu@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@t4/L3F2h9EddOgzwXPIdaQdCGUMTGdtZrr8y9FUM6xrQuAcCGeAVAn3/etCZcZniqFL1FPIqTMuRR/C1oBpxXQAMjFlznFopTUSMjHRgEfjFD4wD0XTHTEkSV5oXxL8d/Yjb0DH/qVc/cckx12TOXvfT3j@LZRsrGOmhM@lBzBWTIqMk8swPTnnGZI4FfAh85INV1zxyWWiFsg78yDZIqXcvpKmMdt7HgRw@5rzyZp0P9AddU2O2J4@u@UyjUuNJkUrNblT/XGcyh7eC3UmJWykHW6zuGZyd9qNSeM7RNz8gyNCB5YgRqhxF8NkGIy8mB0/EEIZjR5GosgubtCkXdTgc/w9zppHDPYLoW7YSmLYTYPJNJAfVfcMXSA3sKgB5OUk73C6Pnp2@GiSb3g2RHZu8kdTgJAnH2dZcBD@uB/A@hI5BgmOcsNEcy542idNdP0QdDRs7YGYLUN/VkAVNfAn@wgI0I6ZMJ4ZJlOqq0tdiHF6iXpHpZPR0k/fSDk7JPtZSejtJrywCWiJFl7mUaI2XdFdl11mbHk4X5Pf1wfJ/G8X16Pb6khV/GmavmDR74YVnnUwsIEHGBRv5mNLDowLf6V9BZQiXyRrmKJ3hvFPu0TayPmO5C1N0gujyA9pGN3jx4ixD/bB39r6/AMPn@@1afjt@mfzoHfjPG7Y8p@ryVFy6OpiD6QRp5z9XsoqZ99z3zgrj4ZcF7KEKAGEuMy0ZLxNAxJ6B2e9F0cQj4hjaPO7OutHvartXggStwck@z7ERbX0V3O33D0udGPxXEzMbghiV@Agob8av3KzgyOmJ6Dtf1UjB2paNQGMaR6DxSbU2T0bOn6fT6ZsWjmFHroZlywvBgPf0w/Aprxim@Bp@tBj0gmUzgdOypidOfk/lkzo3dW/wjRwEf5eMPr0m02XAzQYAOfPRUs4ts09exzyepqEjvMSJEceXlIqMt6hAi2iq6WocfRqKbSwqVG0vUCGtZWP7My@oaN6@r8VirCNskX2V6vyZ5U6N77zYXa2oc2IKF7X3YEHIFMu7n6PVScYjc59oac@wrPAH9aJ7OXjOqdFYw1CglcTrfJHWb5Iu0gJrxATxxwukzeCLAoeF3eIMKy4ZzWsHnAhmFjPVJTGoJfEBIBygxKnKSB2jEYgmhG6KfX0R59tbm2buSZ28pz6gHLGcZiyT0lrIMagGr57oqsIyBv4Y7YxDqzvC4jm3DZTu6i7MV50kzWTOzLHmarAFDThrJ2n4KmHKyn6zdJYeXrD0lx0my9ik4Fn0r@SZZC7sFRnDhlRy30T9g4fjeS9b2UukLwddPDC/MV07WojqFODv8lSgCpMByg9SIS2y2ExTTdw0Y2EiozDJsMV4W1Seah8nSLwf//MNN9EkXDMQ5zi2KzDJMXRo0YiMGzweGjfCTASt6ci0YzfcP79F@qCgKZpMBHS@ehsCDGJ5ILjMjjhiG0ooGPAFB5Ju11Rix2Ej2nugEuUMLpUpezp@oJ5M80E9ReAsitxeZ0Ne6gvRhfS2D4BX4fnhi4nV4XkEnzI4wwjXZ9Aq0kKgvk9cUCut6GZeg9uM1RHPdy5EAWymMwmuJwMZ4OshwtDiHmU2cyXIjoVDcbG/G09CkHO@U2HovJSOuEPTMNcHkHZQMGUO886evK04sHaK2xIIwsJVr814WjQvEizFowetikirvfIBCjOdADzd6J/QltLuBk@JxdpOlsWLdMBSm5VkS51pmk5BYRiNYU93nuUfK6z6axvow9TVMOcO5lhQCiKWMcuH81fkA@d3h8nsoUIdEuJTBKsF69VB6Vby@dpS9hLm1yPZqBWJglt1NrxSOohwWJAftICaZX9fWroj4uOWDC/k80wj6JWk/JFukE9xAt8u6BYeFUoJ7uux5ooHnibaeUFclEutUDoUWGXMK4PCCR5guinY9rrzgq6oYQ2h@W7c@uILd5QqOVx7CowK4l0jOe7k7tWmXy6JvA9vmPshS1RrjjJyWS6NqXngCu6el22jZFjwOO0/uHj568DUYdMvlcjoYo@cL/LDX4lxrNI5zyLS5OhoPVqgtWhY/V4SL3Tgd740c1984tsUrvIQzaxAGdMglbH5BH08HvCzGzy/1XUjH48YoGsA6WXQDfYkroaij45BtBnT1gSCGn9rSAyCheAv0zpK2lqYP83Q6tj42Oh0avjod3LzU6QSjGFZNuCKe/mliQ5l6Ln1umH9V6kwQyMYDu3vInt/fPWJH9/fZvWd7n7KvHT5jz3cfHf2/xV3rVhvLcv7NPEVbwkYDoxs2GFsIW4CwdYLBB4G9vQBrD9IIZm/dtkaAZJu9TvIjL5D8zyPkVfIO@ZWnSOqr6p6LEBgfZ63jtYxmprurq6urq291gXn/@6PN3dqWov/VvXpVWQmtS0Tgw4aS6LrtNT2EVVXLhcIzxZC3@oOJyJ3Mli3f625Xve03PVxTrQdu9/WFvOR63mhDSlVpOzrBGabPERe7/gj6FhwikLaxWNy02EAQtgCK8p7RnraLPW@33/LbPuW1sPcd@F5gbMpUx6ceJHlrTJwdWSQhGiCrDnGUT2hgXVNxl/Lj7obAuKJ/BRIjh4QPbOWUJlz474cpeFg9eFdX8BSxtb@3XTus7e/V1c7@Ab2@/1Tbe0P0rNUPD2qbR0jijO/2t2s7ta0KfxAECjkFFw6/XQaje1HIITtTpfk7br5zA@r@8C156o0VvLp22VQyUAuXPUgf3@34X7zWQsm6DLB8gXkmXxWozHzl4M0HmvOV9wduOM1VMOsfpI4CjlA5X1DrXBsNlg0abyXLeGfMZIs230d0JwpBarwSu3bI8LOjDHBW4mn5nkptQUcFZ9/iAYLHsgFNFT0i2ABlFFbKioNLLSw46wxyg2prdvpw2ym1iRKhfkHR10bVpGQxxbSuDIDC3qHWw3lQsRR@IL6nD8u62tFQMqin4QfJoJ7JByxFa9AdUSs6x@Vo/xLiWa3Kh9@6gx2@FlbPww@bLu9i1zRO0m/cpa4Kg/PBH0aHQ4jJKQ@HOXWDpu9zkYDzI7xWpyMDw5PAjiQT5SqRddsoZ4qETRtXDVrtTeIlI5W4AXpCbnsUqEzZzqlDKAd5PV@Ct5133J6oQEWqO8x7ag2uh8obevkQBj1jC5JBnxkQAReTeITltvWq0HtoOSq5eatGV@tIcuBRo4L2PQQ2byHw94AhQNnETqfJMxVbrwJMv61ZORP0iSNxbvtnPD@xc@uy6SUKaK2tzG/@ly@2JrKT2CcZPUXGjrroizekZSVfZbb7QxrjLFY5TBSkYPOiPxj50oeZZAv4xomnOcqNiY1q@9UQV9cGOkzX2Ov3YpWeERffUesZMeVDamWOl7vzUHxF8YOJ82kSFr07oOOe9a@82N2Zg0ukaw/HL7QQ5rtyHH5ORoyJrD@tSHb8qRB2dK28sb15kv3zVwexR0UsSOhfo3SI/8SYqIuGB9/zscLiEOsuPdJMzLjg8gyltQ6elpYY5QYY7QMvfNrXvW6UwjRRN779HTY209/547dvZSmVhWTS8aKDi0wk3Rx1bKp0uMyp0iogMdlJyJKsz5gvDsMM5fVr2NWgF@BLpwc5gn37VEQ2LUJM684u2yRZdGBc3d0hfFttsEZFFFUc9jLx/sh/zmyWlzbsfKRQomLkzBgR7RjIRduOqaXwfHUL3Pb94Eh@Pxzc2r3YyfTwQ9C274X2Q7hll@6GJdNSDNbDwf55D1iZ3P4usNR2527AMknehhZyesicznw61Ka9v8Zfb/Udjz0Cg7kXJygh0Fhtlz2@ojZesjNSwI6DiRZE9cPt6sGBSsn@hMqS3MOWoaXFIGA/Uu8jbVu/x8IuFy6a4q6tZfFkviQ02sy/@wbzTOLdISr0GsTR9AiFRRTYp@2PRerpmYWXEKx9zwLRUC6J3Vcjg4JjDfiG9oCEbNRpsQZaM5uZlsnHD@JK4JpujqyN4zr8rGEtczfCzQ4ncUBxnSD3HJYls/vvo6yPX5p6ZIEFv0NocItW0jTf0D6hThUPKGMul@zBe7rFdCmU7GWBnTa0g@JXIbnC/nmGYkaSRbishWNiXS@ONWqyPp43yxxWSMQ04ELTUyeKRjMlGBHPX9bjHWpHk14mOQXRIhMBSF/HuYKKn97oKYypEc6T5XBBHh9r84zNscHyFKezGnbp7kyPoQu9Oi0epqsiaXtvVdn/n6pklkjUZGg@szEmkSCvrqw8/R7s6VaY4tmfhS1zyLT8HHUHtL@PQAaTgI/3iXNre45JjxjgHtKJar0ZMFMFaakzY05JtJ0nozh@hIucCxEy8BiPmK7TtdpqPIXbbOgyI8Whc5ZbbYgN4bChMmpuUf/m/uogkL9b36Mfr08GGzJBdfAGWvnv@sPAi6zyYr5dYp9gDZv85g2HPc4m9kxdQMmwGdO9xnZsbScKr9IqJPJ9W7wlbW2dJGq3jjlr4Er4eDGHMM443StNH@9li6V4U3dqu1W1yB4k24mzyNQwZcdkzyO/dx8CLIP5XALTB9vwPQ5e0n/CwTEgiUxszZdh2tjfxY0pQqvmY44ZpNVCtWwtTvd@O2i6PbgEcVKPA5VynlBBPoWt7u/Ys07WC6VEeUIuGPQyVMpJZXMpLkrfcKALSEkQ0pv4HpuwYKlhNCVhXnPeh34ULra8sZyeseakmy@uFVZfWNy6njNyuscvTp3FZjmlaPJ1e93gcnjd@v28f3HVVh01@O1s3Jx8@UOplWfqKdW1/ETc@BZXy3n2nPqc/q6pFwXmXI3gK3ZJjLDCOYm3qtSCivbhpUdKopHwpvklLCSmuFQtdg0XwsRuVO4er56We@VCqXvcOy3ByG@0VB4tFZcy@PCEZlGSMXIzfzw6xZwaP3X1elcKzjI5rqc2DVFsGkJf3rlDv79b2XuTOI3DAgBHYFrXmw/UJYTzHLTZYHuS63nXGX1M5ihwrIUFkjXHVkFFmMrzeTKOY1o@YUa94tBqNhjz34ltzRVyl4NRn1OMR0Swlvrmf7PmjBlTgU8UKMuxb/wmwr6A4ER5MrgYkq8T0aLOFmW5VoTtpB0DcYySLA5TJ6kUbAqBqLblOj61gpznNi@ABGKWf@Nian2dI5gTqwU5PsWDKoc7ZIOJwikecQFCPwO@bUAVvHIP2OzDoubjvYgH@cJnVCO2k2EFeYtXikiB@rf6yvZNXH6dCCCEn5M1V04fceqVFy0kxXaQDxfg4iy58cc1A8wqpVPm0FjAlvrKEXDWFGcaoVpNJvo@dw1yCq3on25Btshvt5oR5rclO5OE76n1WwBacpdy0gZ@OlGxTKxY1hQzmWOkmPsuNXDSRdujdx4Nq4na8jodQlpoMReRA49s36vrXwrrD45R52mIvKRnb6VnE@k5SRekolw5muCjTC/jmVLpr1G@G5WKsjm36iorXrzkqKebOVqSRHlL9@UNcqN@w48yb4RdKVwZJqwnErKxlM8zel9SHiXKhAweph9LuubvZd3zIZaJvK@T9ePX0h3ksfKs1jWZ4tJcz@@8snS4a50CNksRNZWS4hzRUJlBVdY2mFqc0AoO5/w8bDfKEZSlopE4PGZSG@uvUzm9yHiVmUZDrBhvDawZYyRGJa5ziQk3ZoNFqoeTH8VAMEwwmjIjd8MUnujCkxhY5HpkqhUryFsDnJo2PcTLsIv8hj9msCeRM/nSsxPnBPOxNF6sm5MEYqH7KDWbTElpAnMR@agbdc8sEtU9mYY4W0jsxU6Bwzo9scFu4xj8USgn4oLCSIpbdA9TNKWjDEXDvnd1IRJvrP/NL1pvXFpjDzreWFWwzXDZCstKGLiPvGAUwDcUu7gJLgeDDm4decF3zSbU2q3I8gquWyKIsZk9Z9Wg2SP5HTxpg3QqlFP7gHwNBZEoIbg8P4cxGSxg@9cQrThx8Uc5q9KbyIEGjZmny2Jm7ik432AB3PHP40hIz8noAaWDgdv0chat0QJa/VjS1LavI4HyeTrsRuB9jKa0l5b110u/@fvWG9znPi8WnhZjJLvS18GF3NNnkYEVEckkLMNz4ErxmWXF7oabcjecBUBH7WKi/0C86V15vZ5nVWjG4IwBLVoDb3jltXKWdeCFl8CAC1bGzSTssPuXw6Yc7tCiyyVmhJVw4Mh1GHEYfjE/y3Vxk@/KHAuXVtFtM3X1ld8CAY3FSbuP22G@sICbAKEHCnW9ERFl0VZJlPjuWePCa5cuDqKIGvBzErubCMnQ64/8JvUMn2RZHQIl1yBRZb3WFCZUX7Pjwjg4NwsBmMdEFDAImKuk@3Cw9KX5D@GgdMPMHbtreiZP0q/PY4WGuzf0SfpGBOZe4WIx3KmDD9/W6qq@v3P4sXJQVfT8/mD/Q227uq02P/EdNy7K2f@ueru/S9IlvE2XW/N9@pCq1KlkihOsyt4nVf3l/UG1Xlf7B6r27v1ujaAR@IPK3mGtWndUbW9r92ibb98JgtrbP1S7tXe1Q8p2uO9wraaYFZVT@zvqXfVg6y29VjZru7XDT1zjTu1wD5XhVr@i3lcODmtbR7uVA/X@6OD9fr2q0DBru1bf2q3U3lW3c1Q/1amqH6p7h6r@trK7O9XQ/Y971QPFSgKxVm5WCcvKJm1hURO3c7t2UN06RIOipy0iHiG466j6@@pWDQ/VX6rUnMrBJ0cDrVf/ekSZKFFtV95V3lDjrMx3qEL9snV0UIW3JFCifrRZP6wdHh1W1Zv9/W2mdb168KG2Va2XlLW7X2eCHdWrjkJIQ66aYBC1KJ2eN4/qNaZbbe@Q5oyj99B3sKmTPxJhCMsKFd1mAkMNAq0lIu0ffAJU0IE7wFEf31bp@wFoytSqgArQqNg6jGejComIh/Fmqr3qm93am@reVhXJ@wDzsVav2tRhtToy1KCQ8YlYhyo94lajnwgveSRmtQznOtydqrajKtsfasBc5yYOqNc0tzDZtt5qmufgozd2iOL3cWbgduMHK@3bn648OKe8fSIz@4wm9Ji0tb9dpRlZu7ZKRQlHNOusTblSiqfRTBMm0mvCZU3LO7s8b/i9dh82pmExOfjoBucOYvbYCHhyYt0Tukqfr3CBdLrR@FBp0Ea33mjYzkNKJtD4Xgl9DH5fLlu3EXEQsPPGwc/Ll0L39QShNp7oi05W1MMFBHIK9Z@I6pvb9WyVz7c8XQzG@wBsjo4CuTa5wFUKiUY2dkSklqhKPpngd1@zAxfMGPC5ZgPnpNCM5Ez9gP70vkUvMjnEPpB0luOufB6bWEbD/@KZaqQSdonAf7RHAr/NVeYCz/v9PFOIV4c9f@68329lbNuU4bwj2geeZ@zvFD/zzqeKZ6fLM7J87axDCARm381LmPD@WZNM6X7JDbllGfxpjPjHNtiIzwecmnJVfFitDy0zT6Q4NJIcpV1bwLyCOxlrvneVX2ofsZsrLD8rTX1/G36XsQV9QTixpQnvmMud8s/bU8lAA4x9cRBJfO0hI5@PlTH6JmHma8p4gUzXfguaPzRXX3g8rxNJaCF76XbidWI2HvrjOPYkh98cVN5tHu3skOgEts/WVp6vlqzQ7dYvjvx@Qj3saZa9jg1oHqd1GifFRskWLXx4pMQ8fEfszwyczyMj/LabTuOP8PMQ6m0kNZkgyNDcAGGLelDRS3mgQ0qxA45HluHXmSNTM0Am0VQbrem6Y17iu7RWYh7QyiydCffaGH8AOxz@ZoiHDdIMpFmMfe8S59LuguVeaseoivLmhh33IEsuZfhY3LiFNOCjLtafhXUtv2nejvViIKqMGK/c7VySkHg0jYUyehU9Gdnv2c@IPgBm72H05RfNb/T4STu4Y3d3bjCqjOpExp2wJM6po8No3ehjDfkUMTTgVM3UtK5wym9rpHjs6ePk0DFIbDQwKgjQAh3fJOBS6EdkukrWgH29YKuvwqlw3gE4Jc2x@p04d1ZzNJSS8R@i341XCiWwQicnQrXrsA7LZPkU@rEw5EyQ6afowfD/gTSZAX@ddpwEPaJWzAnggyjJUIVWtH1lovjX5qIhdrsRUTP@6VME5ibeMRdhw/TtzVjsa4gEuncm5sMndnvYzswgAJgcBxvx8RuqpF24tHV6nbJ1cdyT9JrdQUbpucJMFbfgZldPHV52OeZuBS@2suWsKVbhLhVVr2XjdsajnrZMU1t59ThICTjb@P/IL/IBSDjgmUsvRGt1mrMKepQZOaBdLcUmnFboMYmWpTd33totqpiLzITs1zdfhlAEegP43G4nBxTpK1HPTXpc5JlYHbIXPPgTxzYZk492WXfGipgdD3Aet/gwBDFHRteYIDoCnV31RdBU5jEriqCSSOsw8jMIcWvniLQ8rV6H2PPJJDg0xP6oJ47sPTnVMjly4uBDYxg3l8@pd@6EUO48rNnCYvnFet@B7iIqk2MJXR7xVZr9/pCWji7aTTg6/sTOqY/60MHrBZdD7b@Q5jN/qE8kzKKfqsGySXbvPM2ID3lGLfBHsFZo5Zg/uEldDxqi4p5knF1VGWJew6Mb5tDRHy8VVWY9SlknmrBbUibiulpV375JLiGodhnqMQX9INxcsM4m14N7h3D4XfeHv2PuxxKo1/JaoWfSGEg@C5ROqvXYx2NzJE0f9AM@0aCuwAlISImiHKSFiqo0Rz/X7KT1mlKRd0z4LuWW/Hg9IZMabSmqKGJcXTsx32qWOhNUWtauQUNnocXlFUZl1obr5s7NGHsLTV5bq9RJLxQpL2URUX5slo54ErkZPn3Ckz7kLz8OMHroC@649RIUCGPNinvV23KO8YNOwUffG7biZ6K0kmm5Axy/8dan32NeNEeH2u1f0x0F3oR2AM28P84zjEbmL/2LXmOr33HP/b7v0j4NbuDHIvHwOOFHdNj5sH8dcOggTmjFMrUm0bP4lxE3bHgP7yVLMddcwcgbZOJqCqPhpHIhbiL45BxKgFEsUebvwbSPtLDMs5WokJW0P2V9vKJdurPs0@KswnKjDwBawG1MaVCIDemIDZNixqelWxnO7ssQw/FMZZVr36Gxl8D4BZGIr2ESGBtkbqklxBuBndmdGB@3xk6LfRAO4WjJ2/YQCifI8GfHRXhmkiKvoCnwUhXXCrGicosyhh9CPEzuJvfy838w9oTAT6BffDqLW2YxAou4tvG2FMh@RXsZJVxYPdBnGc2SmKSYf@73YuaHHIRiPA01mTy5ixqs@UOLIu1m7xZXYkRmaOODCHeZBomcxsTGpLKgFmz224ElSGWUKdzNsN739Gd58OMSV07OIJi2NORMDOm7SNUkKiEA7pR6bRxl8an8/RGzvPzQXpsiYHmWylksEHMmZVYubIHiy/yKa63@kIRxaop6WtVjIRj1BwsPpN6dsmOmZ7ZZtG7a9ncVgYXZyjRZLraYtOUJHiclaxqfKaZJUow1zYiHsH3l55DNp4k4Ljcw3sqNyXfocBfNIr2pcFIJ@7slYx@T4hU0es1EEw4pxh1OSkvh9@MGNbxxtwTRMGV71WCJ0YDIaEzkMQZqikwhlR5OIeY@jfsUPVpEOdTbItrF@@dOok4ryRmXpyYp4eQS9ITjdhhtklwatKF8ATdxssINhVS44Bw7E77KK2bP4GQYCQIQq2IvG51DyQlu1FlTfMTRAdqZBrSFipBE9LQR13AInf6HBGOv/PpwR2s8NCbZ4mlJII1DSLSr4Fz3QTL25vR63BgzlFukoCE@gxRhi27JpouHt@pn20L5CIKU5mSt6Vtw0BhbLRE29Cee1BhjDRxVpUsmRlRyIDRYNNBYoF3KeceT7SpWf/5QOB7aDXoY0QZCPmfws6RLwJ33aiGkNoqMWxNksTW5ZbTZKrshRSKGkneQXw9FWeryxpUAeIIxlS8XCQLcmjL2uBRg1ztxzksgqvuICpaLGJb0kb2iRnqeM9JBVJ3h2UosR2FWjhdxGNmZQGhhMTtPhAitWWZniaDQRDcTl1iO57PbE@WgBbHhfaE4dYXulSQNw54TAnLA54IdSZTjonIKmoM58dmKnUgM@ZtTXxRiqYXpVKJPiOFxtjidulZIpCaqXV5OFk2UJHrY8VoTiUQKO45wKBV@7h@bpsRdnoc6obFNRmKVofWzEZCbdpm0b8v9Fqh1Nso2awwDL24ZbrZfDQmxknDKfr8DdrXAVwbw3f7TrTWaqQYTHSuA/dIZY5eMbAh5xZrCVI9mYadrPO2FDgrMnrbfVh8Od3YSbl/PJkbRqOsNVwqFApj4LO783uhW4yjJ7@eTufPty04nP7j@y/DDWZ5lv@dxSICXZgftUZfQoAhy/eG5RIYADpQVubPakBV7/ct2Ox6CATeU6DzqNsmpvSEonoD8UOnlwyEfADFIPcH@igaifb@qcPRdu7LQ1FDMNRSVhkrwVcrcnhF58KEN/ezwpoqBQTAbbSaat@zyxlfMIIhswp3F7ovtr5F6cuqt1@n0HfURwYfhKWDuZrrAzk68QEGy4IaRrXsvA/ZH6yjvyu/E7IqRJc7rAGcmJhNnwviFh2/8A@@8Oh5kUsefUzStUJOX0Mwl@Kd2VOo8ZWtn8Q8AK3xIaD8od9cdZJpMp@nMNNXrERw9EUZPi87MvU8ii81nYppm388Nos5GN8fOGqjpNq8FjC977l5uyR3ZQ@KmTsbFNmhYEBgaJ/hceVgJmJr948Ti1ajdfphU5DAA0rE/JBElEsrPCUS@A@ARqIcf0RNetP8pS8N6Z8qhiCxwEKzjttxBgQYKWNbjZvmP60ylUlHzg6UlVals0kM2qyqbFbWND5ubapveN/H@pLy8slISmbttf6WPm@bjjdokGHzCudS8GG7TK6WVYTcGbW108Xy@PO@U5hvl9Y1SkD@ubMKsn57@@5//9b//5d/yFf3yH3jZ5Jfjz2GmXC6Xn29@nX9yU8L78fbpwvzZ8fzgdOG8BC77X/Ya3q@Nsm6kPpobnllpmQViX1mP1Oyz2fuMLqpMTMCuO/ydpMtLlW4G@bT@GkjkKJax6aYX@@7BjvKMtvAm6MD0Vp6QSBPQCY7jqXeaHhTwaL4hShIu0AOV8nK3Yg7u4Q4mzBDeqqS1Jx5es155sGmJPCnAFpdmrKzfC7weTsCveM0rzbMsl379UUPzb/7zu@B8sz9WiycZtVhQi45aTKX4p7j6gr7a83kf1rmSjbYDqZRDKdHVAtQMVeDzQo/3DxxrZ4rcljXPIXsAybip4MxiBeeEuz82lpGAa8G5NYdQnEqOSPiSCUXSX@d7N9QtXynHTSphasMLhYbexXBlsRuVsH@xBHIDUQSIau4KQV72qUrc9LFFMp7y5ovua4ujCTFgkPXgzQ6Pe3yguWi@p3WeE3sphDli9Xn5irmxJMbQjDZSpP4IAb5Qke1kgS0JF9ILlmh5x1rJzRQr7Hj7NPOJrsPEGxnddCn0p4oxgWhzxwk339N2LVqRW65XVMoPr1diVaWmdb@VFSvSveyM/IE2V@DaMaC@hrXdyEhCjzIggSM@@1/eHmF8UGA8RU11iwTLmqhWH02XkdDTpunUwXZObo5iRMh/ztDY/jY1tu08W4kYdhAeYKRCVb6263cC7XVlyMQ@d4dniA7otjmg2kjuzfg8D9FXpzDut0OkcwyZVc6j8UxNSQ@G7nnXdVR6r384dCc1mrZo5TNq5mxqIVwwAQkMPl31rOYZhKVFukuYImFTWHMIwQs6Ex0eTfo2FdqcoEvNUNBuVzAIEuzElPS@Jfpqio4RV/9AJ8RRviW8w9tILWJZ8kLTSENKxc1meJjdGjqWqSE@dsKBk7IE1XBkGl7QhS4x0Xb54pckeQc@AnTdKW0FqE0RVl@gfsxO517PTUxOg45lDP3zJSXzIsYzh6IUbSTLxEktRhHvgBWtIz8nvUDI3GTcGVlzmczcSaDDuaXj8wg7@Q518fOu8sMAdBzAjC1D1FHPF2E5NUNFMTByqsaa/wSh3XHPCb/JtTsBK56kM68e5e3jzye908XMSe/byRebMdEi2cyyWZXWl9lGYumxQjNj3km8Gq20wLgaPOklM5z0lNiwxEhAiOQzx5/zp9/yhNBJGjHpT9JCkESXAZP8/fXlAT5/C810Eot82pqzF23T@ZlXRVvR3Mq/6EP5YMsvYWE2lXxMT/ucYZtAsZ3uH5dichLk15YLz5aLz2gndO6Ns0PvEvNtNrg888a0lAiwnaWp5@RLghsShLgZB26JPo6pnRLWRGxPAm2kpEWoHuZcjxWyFZXJCU9QfqIyu0uFiYsd5nFx@YgNv6OI5Uxe9gUlqoMx7stg/gz6XdTjBpBr09YhwpHQMhAdET5CzQKyCb5yF4faZrgssJ1TTm3BdysDoe7Np2OzRa/fy@rFmp1bKGERDauZzlphrTA9Rm8N0cQIndeLqYVHqrjx6vl//fv@H@lRemM5/3FIv6P0H@nVtbQ80gO9PTVvV@mN9Dqyrd6kJ3naA9Pj8//6Tyq/8ReCg5TJOv3ZWDGwVifpjWyZi3xLb6zSQ3F5mer9n7/9jdowLzs2xGKdbziKESsZimy5PeZdSlc1tFK2pQuRWGHDLMAQDUPam9MLFKPGy2sFPqZLa62KK097vjL6KHqKZ8WsEasKyUmG0aeglZEUKKOCrIA0KhRtFdPdMGobYN4ITfXr49xqQDuAX7U6R1hlqLrxOIDK0Lxsi6gDM1Ij7eflYaPwKhWqd7xMGZ2SkllCYmunZe3a09L/AQ)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/9cpf4)

Whython is separated from Python 3 by [function composition](https://github.com/pxeger/whython/releases/tag/v3.10.0y2):

```python
try:len[id];print(349)
except:print(1)
```

Try it in [Whython](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728PKOyJCM_b8GCpaUlaboWN9VKiiqtclLzojNTYq0LijLzSjSMTSw1uVIrklMLSqwgIoaaENVQTTDNAA) and [Python 3](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31UqKKq1yUvOiM1NirQuKMvNKNIxNLDW5UiuSUwtKrCAihpoQ1VBNMM0A).

Answer (score 3):

## 358. [A Slow Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Slow_Language), 15960 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx r3o5o8ox xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcu c 11 xx   .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{










































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrl61op>a>std[]!!92[ ]?42e>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NYdiD4saPg@RFXoCpJigRAgG9SpFKpVFaqKrOUnVJWlYtkMkESJJECASZASmRKyuju2e11255ZT097ot32uNo969n2eiLGO7Gzbu/YMxH2fpxwzCf/gPRjY8Ox4f4HveecC4CgREqZ7XHExMZCInCf55577rnnnvvAQUf3hj/7WQwv9sSx5gPLmbCJ4U1YzzVPDVdm9@bsrm56eS0rCJhq1x1MR4Y98SpCjKmMWbo9mOoDg/VNa2K4aeYZBusYlnMG8Rpj21N76hm9OviyjNnGGTuwu2YPILCJc2LY5mvDhbgcY/cN62J0MWFdZzTS7Z7Hxq5pTyg2z9gTHTz9afeE6R1v4urdienYEFVg7Jlt6aNOT2eUfOwaPFORAajuCeVZjikx9thxPQNKcLqG5zkYWIZA3TWdR7uffnQlvZphH@mA1NgyZleKV1X2uWm4vas5NPbZ8YMHV0Oz7BPJsdmD6yipObY7nTgHk6vw82x3YNg60@SyrF2NLAAxJ4ZVypQyV6OK0J7GxOwulQMRD0wXWlf3W5F1dRtaC9tyixmj8WTOJN7@umWFbesx3WNTb6pblM6ejjqGGyT0Jro7Me0BOzMnQzYZml6Yj1J7Y71rSD3DMkfmxOgxy4RMTt@HAqDtHjsx5meOC03uw3Rsaw4Zja7ZNzFLgAcAxCsxGRoczkifQyPbE2AOpjMP0LCMAFpSiEH6@0ZnOmDOdDKeThjg1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadaBOCAyhZ8NDdtnZgAnA4hjh2P1ckqoGQue13s9lgE@BjxODGYC1QitCstmIZw5LlANUgUY@cCIr3kdjRm0GTRR36mwfCYD8fthCGKrW57jI7OMGkba0FepzRDuE9cZuPoIqNEziKafHTxhXtdxwQc/TMv7001guvqEbW@z@P6n9@OsHjaL7HaEsIlq7ByaIBZEslPdmgKHRFvCgfZxw9wCNll8I15hcSCLlmG5HMtBty0xLQ9EUjNlcED/17Iq/ApMK7GcCj0oH09jOX1XH5iWwaEMEEoRGV/LMw3umRzLqiWecuBYfZ6sS4UVWbbECkVWzLMi3MusrEFpCDrH1HIefgX4AbQyoKLCL5vjgBZ8D3yKvLbH@vrItOY@dALfZXmVFQEi4KsCZK0EEOCZzeIvCz9Ca/mKwp4MgdpD/RTAS5Z5gtLICAUSNqECD2VrSyGJiCKXF@8NsXggHRAtX2JFKL4AlMgBCkBZrQTF5zO8It7QsCw/29DDbIRtMQM/wLwIdCgB9TNAywwSswg/8IO800CwaSDFNBBMGggTTQN3FouAdAWIK0BTFnx6DXXvBAri5Wg9Ij5IdACjIrVRiKlIJIAArcWy0GYFlgNGyCIj5LMM8AdcigUGcqykslKOlYoM6FnOMGgbFfBCLlFBfqqAj4rAoP1VYAAVcFKB2ioAVbN5JkSIrWYxHvJmIS@QRs1Bnhy4oeHUAv4gH3CGCkWqUKamlRdMCLhpeahvPkvcqRWgdYsQB3TTAFcN2EkDbLUSxGPeEtCwhMxbjKc5IXSkA7QKsjvwIRAjD/gQXEgLbq2Y5fTTrfFQ76C05jk7fcxawG5QQDJC1gxWD545pCagkgEw2AsAfQ04IAvkyELTZnNY/KUAHZgP11HxB1Lic@z6KMxQYIOwckgUL3gyYQfiJgnScVlygiizgDdhuOjqKNawkxskpAI45kRmUAiMrYZziroASZqlYjySRh0Xh34YOnqG6zJMC/qClya55U07nvFqioPTAq8@CEID5GVfN60QAeqc@oSkKjzjHpQ3X0a77zoj6sEjlEuW44zXjAEgBc8Q0EPnzFigvhCS@nhswVAE4QYfCQGZM52UGNJ4oqVyhCAT5usOTQBIRYEIN12jS7T3qw65syDsl1GsMK1@J4tQ7kXGqCwbOyC/PcxjTy2rAoOH0WXZutIzThUM4ePY8viFOAQjG4xPPoiODgoIYk5YhJDuaDKNmcdBy3rOaLlqXGgdhFUfmjjaWGf6HFqvD/LKmOkjUJMY6iI2jJAj4BjegtgSoAhitQ5Yz7HjkxDKmQuaAVQ6rAlpH0iTiTkyQKV0IAu2eI6QRpFJmHXmwMpErZxMOiTH5AqhZOEqoXhALhLAOwuMob1pF6mGZZs2cRCMPR4qTq6h93iYMHFZs6nDz4VBcuyrzTI6MOERohbRumCENYD6vjrTJYg48Bu2B7qaJzMTlVrg/IHTB2Y7M6HuoC5B1gXsLhEBSRAGzeSuLBDJkYFGJxYzWXc8ZhAOSgiw54NMCcZ156XJXkOkNQS9rDt13TmbjaElzBGkmnSdfh@497UxHgIINuqx7rwL3RMaGblH6Dkkkbrj5WoufJsGpLFR09t78otsYADZQQvoo8qPLL@owHhMVSBS6DbXEGwdKIVV6I7nRBYAE@boO46M4T3H8IhZHPck7PpYmGcMqGtAP@svhNEINR7gUps0tR5IHr97IXwsUFhZGSzK54KPDBu6The4Ejo9NB@26S7rw8wloheg8qZ3u8Z44vOJQ@LMtCNK1OEDVKIoVPKByd5Q2LzLtq9wDSQNOSeiIKBSiaiPfd1OR1nrT49AZbCNhR7PJYs1v1Y8pDi9Urr4AtMsYfBCXIPDmLoEapQkJKYTFCUoHc3uEGXhBKUNKTHQ29zp9epDWLR4d8Skflg2YqOC2BFkJQxCPNbDkOBnXQckjy2EVV8KwKRLAbeA1r3RCshOiKTVi4bKii6DULwN6MixnRVQgZghXEyyHENtQcx4hFJDt0JmpO7iLbURCuzFjB0HMhhDx2PHhZ7Bhc6cpmfUZBHu8mc1iXCsSMJsf3lohSEjjgP@BEdByDC2YC5HXQx7KqirOkgKEGJ81gEyz@ElRhCmXk@wfPzOSPRzZoKx1LYN1Hh1d86BQPVgeIaC5sx0XRCDpzhI8DEoGExk4lMYE2D@hZIVyUH9/mrhMnL03rRjzq5ObboYKL/0hFPdZX2c1bigdEAnSsT7XjxZpXDKGYkSFWc8USgrv4uQkBLJ0OSJPkyUYJB4AILmaG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ7MyHU09rE@nlzF7iWEIdOMTqBfk6/KBjB8SxLcJQwjTDBCkTFCd0HPgE4Iqnu53Ovo7AKkB0zRZ3uUG5VMeqpyLizLsHthWT4hEJdofWVehOd2ySFFRjWsASanmtMgsUTAd6QEZRQhQFH8sRUDSNvjcaTX8MCpTYsbLMFVkSQ7D5V9GAAShIwJyofZNSdtX125cydQXDZqNWA20KZAbPaS0WlCsAokg6SGxDJpI34h8sQ5mmDfSCShvpj4kmMDahNwaq3OzidDF3oc@S8FSARkFWzk5ICwfjt/ap5Me1cb2sZATCRirwOlyexOxKoAgz/vDbWbqBpfoipMJeJIVWRezE@grzEvhWKDin4y1/BQ/a35qERaOIEY@Ly6kkQ8qx@2YOi9edfyVQLugs7OpVEH0D/xVwdCQZT2dYKg017rqRwIdgcOhz3ZPX5Y8/sij1Q6pl1ZCrCcrm5R8CYmF4O8jw7uPd19@ovtFTAss1O5GqCYuVIBh9rpTBrYUyUna5XNKIwF4Pvtm2FjxuU0ouBHM8mZRVSleRcGl1lAzsOnn1wlCWhCSA4qAdz4u6LS8DSgdAkd3RteGYTZIJWCIsMsQVomHbAAZuhA1DFeD/B5Mn39GhvvKlJjPxwxs6Y6BxAEKgd2kE/GyCsKWBDV6fMRkfKCFmrauHq7cEVTBvh8hFrzVWRIlY6wzEeHD/af1gisv1ghURLFm4Aupbs9GXjemvYMYVUaEH/g6rKUvEAc9WnCdSWBu90lAi/alq2BDwBwriM7TLJGQdW8IeC@d7VuFCp1Qw4gP0G4qldG9aHu@yIawQOHuC5OeVeNohSxGKzCoJUjVhi7PGx183mjmCtHh63uosxeFCittMI4EOiNLkSdeBKGyAst0lerffSPHl1D3CMlEqYCUoCZZzGZyvIsAWcvksninrIHMzTHMuTPSeKJTEwqSjxYbJW7Hk0@I@n3Z@YkkUnyp5qEtFD67u6Bdj9I7K8D0koGTRpwLo4jk9vHTZOuBzxiO5YzcNgW5OHaYVAgqE1rq7k7cOxrLaRjIFY1hvsuIH9x4UYfw1hjvqaJI@WKTlf5Do5ue2cgpdVCFolEFCJQCqWXX@qnOpBrUe@jgy/3YRBR85lM6M7QBSSI5CFyoasbCaUAJkFBso/PygqGezDXensQIUU2QbDSvqALM@4uolcGksSUlZXpV6L0sXON4i@d@RXWghDOWuCIkOzg0yePDj7df7z7RXOi5fNL/lymXADCQXkd0IXkIacb9tYt3jWxWgguBn3Dxe4FUmAKE5RgCX7quSC4ZUwicwTWcA3fvUp87AztuJe8WpkzjJVe2l3OQo@x8/GkfkaYaPcsnIy4fAsQx3Pkn@FkMvYqigK9fDjtyDBpVV52HUsfKJQPBgbLUlScuhwc4rqGtyoHIOPNDZ6DL26B6jCnFUTdGjkweaGNRBQNLMHB06qVZQ6GMBfG3UbDTcohB1NtlB7MEGCurIR1IwFMPqCt/wzaSeSs/YGqlThfqxktp4hBsqXuD2k3@gZMnRIwWgEpkle8rHmneYfNQUojpKtAYkzeokUOj@FYYDFQJGnVFOf5AXFIWuB6KcoKotGrKa7mgpRS8plcUS3kFZiWwTQNdFYJ19ykkT7pDqWJIwE8yenTukGEC/teV7f78pbvCJAFve9DqGq28bzZtFugoDfvEG64mdeYtxpqK1ll17Ns@emTVeDepeoh7wYBwLvkBNakJ1sjz3r6dXHW06l39ZgyGY39MUcas8e7oEi9dkBe94xo38MMSjRS2VpKq2DiN8qKBSELswp4Q0op0KFgpAXWUxAvCZReVA@Bc0BuRTKwxWoGrwffNI/IEZx0I9@bTtyjlX/Ua3C11BsDEWmxuYtS2sP1wQmMjiHno5SGxkUhzc6MOK6j6x5frYRM/sZpkB/maiEEWpUPV6TtcKsYmIBy0fQcJAfwFS6bDherjDjpB06DAgknXHwADcKm3YMByBnIzCuyyyvCS6KQ5Sqd2M6ZjdA6BitJHXPCF/udqYsbiGYvWjdIntV4GoBGlYvIddpp7BhdvsrKM1MtYBKos5ExcnApAbQrEgUGVUHnu5Q4F/RwxRq6VUbCbRiAL7G7eyDFugZfL5JGOIkCltpn8Ymr7EpfKrr0Grj5Bt0KKx9pYr/RjwMCLO8Z0yqJvwJK2okzokSf03oLRt4L1F1hPJ8MocbAYaJec8aGfXXOx2eEiWSV9nbjcRD4pp04j29sbMQr8Xo8Da4dcG2jawddKXDtkEsiF6aT0UU50uTC2AblwLBW/LIRQJ4lW8gDM9QcXpvjhN6oVLKttN5Q/aeGzyQ0BVAeUkv4ADjxZK2GzmRSrJ/hng3o75G67yHvHHVdc@yT4GNQCLjfp0GWiADTe9TmXaOKc9ObKTKquTBpNFDFTLjxZiPTbDXPm71U8zKextzJql6D@SEIr0liJA9cZzoGxa2Rq0gg25KNbKVV7dTimfhWIlGSLChITyY/LCVTOqd1Im4ATyWazTiQ1KdOozt0Cd4srSWTIaEAj74JswzLSsTl8xKU30m2kqk45E3G0yCWa/E40KWLRPCo0rgiwJnogTkDUkLHhCEuuqdAApI2p7C7fmmMh3M3miBcdQMtG1fQFwcA8JwESvGolHzN80cVuqWZfqD38nSg3OLiHepL4zmX7gLHtKksHTcJxt1TqT9yJrrymQyTJjkyXMY34ookwUhIMRwSVfux6WEX1m3DmXrRlcaVC6BYOoQeD6cgLIMzP2ngKnMsGN2hw@KbdwE6C/d7cCjBrSuJb4AFAHpdGX4oRFErwc0S0C7olIYJcpHOt9CqjEpIcNETrM3nC@NXclhalfKwDBZkDmzHNSQgCeQQ6EgKHXQS6sw/FXNAK1/X9iX8WBrScOJtGiARH1iOTrTl4jqyHzQeRfLD/ByyPDV6ggXyow/iUeZt4Ro9ZUugXVrHHcIIAbVBSayFrTXyIxTHG/fkyQyyCgkccKORfHYHSucZ62maVujm@5UgDrkCiD2ERsJZqQ1T3CBKUiEy6TfyPl8WCubonx7e3@drJzTY4vCK62jtkdObgl7pz5ueGvYgzfaBn0zbGZlAhiD/6xPrqeNM@CwfPOtWZvik2RxNLZ3WfK4uy9yYr@t0HIuWgm7Kukg/dT3d0vkiVBC7@9lj0PWfHR/V5EokkaKfjm4sG9chVxfL6XkQ3XOk/dZge8jjjClu5kUct4KjdChm/IgCRkz9g3TQRkF4EcODLoV7KH54CcNHeIgOdGV/FYG8YaCfsEwJ8WAdniLyA8/VzCWGr52DhelUSscVxwW256pG4aeTfn8pOEvBJxKKJmsRnKNgfsBuaY4YRSnPE@Fpu6U0UUAFShMeulubrkjpxnQCTw53Fh@HhxCGhhVsLT4FjQW3z2DQt1CvgkkLquj8YJwBGvYYd0lIdOPeG@uCEupdW8@AzjaWeGohtkEdCAY3BVUaYVNh/tp3lbqQ7fh7lh4Xqw7M@WlZZbvOd7lxTuXy6ZzCV@U32wBiu14NTjGtS4YlxeNhMoJKuEEOqiZt7F@ranhMw6PFdoGyVAVPgenETMtIzVlxv3URVzwiQ5@Jzebsw4z2BcxL8Aja5h1lYFSxwHX0qgYxcV@H7cyZBBofpuIL190hyBmWmi2TEtpnavcdqyfxXTJgGMbnV9hA/iGF8GicfwLSMN3gVBwdS@RZUb5GDtRdg3ulSevXE0SO4IWAoPucs4uT9OkFa8CQdyp7Y8uctNilPHHaQyTJZOraVw/rcR3UdfW5J/hnXGps9@lHnzUyLQ5BGOm481XirTgLznyC4gyKEh7OBRee1JmYE9IE6CSCifVVZUBqRpskgD7A4AVUWViQXyNE/cK4WNSlb8BMNWEg5t58lGZG8lLuW/pkYtic5/j243py830iv5gaFb/jbzpUWIZ2ZkAzNTEOUKyyo@P7@0@fysC5XiK@jzs4FeiOencICsq6SgeUjFa@wj7sxdmHmCeJ03YBuhrMPtp@fmDqKjA9zD@gdJQdA8NNQGASN1@6EEz7XZSRa2g@gfC8VXdCNAqBJYwk1ImAVVbi/8zmUy0fzwpwfIooCeRO3KkAbc2kPLXNV7IHAw3prZAkzierMF7UNhMkxTbVJHGPa45w6xhmWKQ0Qg0aDSa9BikHiUXWalX5GQBIixMwd4DUFUVqCjoaXFODpq9BMKg0BMHPXnvDnjcyUrmV2lwFig6X@ad6ef0jcBHCMmjPWFnsZoL6@7WOzHHge4Fccj@j6fSVI@0VtskdIl9zpuTBgSkSOnS@avmc1PIpLOhkKEpoKQYrEoiEmH/m2udZiifJD3MezEYBiSQ7D4muIcnZxQXRkG1qjGgILpXxxrgMZp8gmB45UJtH/nnrqHZAvdU/SIJ9timIwTRreacWY7gKr5xe0U6lUzGaj2uHpn3i0H5P6GpnZDWPGmGYe3RiXc/ZN70h3ZaShjjwtNo67LxRp0@3FQlo28PfUKcAWlD3dWFQInXlKT1obX1FycuHSJaK7Rj9qT2g3Ud0M@nVLSmlcokS9zsdc11SIAKeCwueK5KBkEJ@1uScrAYHuHEpBsYjEFx89rKo@tXzR2yJ7jA6TCCX//zP3@gB/a@3zhAGClx5DB1tGLqxpaT@2sbys6KHbqsbli@QTy1TJ8KQ6zaQXd2FKulW6FgNmjbhJQmG/xFuKfgtDryJN9Aab2AzjjnfEQyeqwtZtalmg8jsrkt75TwWL4q2f2Bi1yMicCXINCgTiS7eCMaMb8FEptgoxm5HKjg0xYiZebsPp5Mpv4PiemsjmmP83dQ3/ZSZvN5RDZg66h3TuKHJXf1k2nOk8ckg1FMLK9Iuak97wBKoA/52cBudq6vPK@iaAxhng@e6ZIuhTTmjx21c4dlTbyx1aBbe4z7qCKMbSnAtfl@XxPTfiAod66lmWnR7R070oQOj@KchFDxrKkWIZl4hs6V35qiDDN@fy8KTBSBxat1UKpNds7U8Hq/PjzNJyl8ur849k7ucHqvWCBR@nlXiq2hUYf@E6y2tCsOVOdItSetFnGuF@aqDCdeShnualMc4xR2d05Utt6A@DkjdqaW7C9cNLL7AI9hGWLci7Q8bT8yuA@rAmKlFWdWCoSMyYJDIDI7GLQrC48R0ixx/MFeRsQfTQhzEpdC1WgQ43QkeGV3DU@8g0PhRTTwQG2ES2VlHqa5zhr@16sMQpqb8vnpEe70Sq3cQTpLVtXQYx9cOB0uLg7j4eAujnpmeQbfVhD1Zieika60MX@4CwbJfdBnvNrb2TMvx2BHdbyLQwAUq8Ptqho7S0tRtiRbDo@4bZFBwxmHRoLo1cKxCaaDocFvb6lO3j3Lff76rhAsllKreIqEC9cexVf@5Vq6fKO7JbQ1Eb4G5eL414rxhiF0lpvy9l/W1g4kBbtytrtmDTIlyygpf6ltTMG65nOnz4PlzDB3rSBsMHeM5qdOg3WGGcgkcE5er2D9PabmbS@u9m1C6BrZ4WyUijXtiGTBY0f1akzIto75nDjWTeXcR1bemxtRYOdE47Lw08F3lGyYZ745Uxq/Gpr9Sj5sD@GpKmOq1PzN8J6xxnEbfjcJEt8yucbsqsyzUxqB9j3Hq/AQcT9BxPcfAno6XWnVpdmY/vZlkw3HQpZ3eEnYY875yqHSLprSkn3sG/W6cMfEZHh4Qq@UymYyvwER2XJY8N82ksmHelya/LxVMIYuSF2lxl82NOFeXQWSJHkFcK4K0dRN7SlwuK7ZpG5M53t9RmnYcx3qflgKh2jNRFQPNko7a3tRi19Qd/yUStli68HDBo9Nft2jBRxt/bgn0wUnzTY0e3RJ6p9aUcNNzhBtSy96bl28iG0y3lYIvc@OaED98a63XJf3VEFUuycUbex3XUJ2OYen8MSvkboJXlrM3wlsWGv5mLW7u8i3dxVZ87IpQGs@BWGYPZilDY2SQ9wYtX@@h3QH/sTbRzMHfuuiZYXSV2b7RXZdgbIJcsPG@tIccUZYmjg3zqwme88N5ioUnSf3QdRI42PVbSeSDkT4wuCGMmyTlYsECT9Pwad3CuXrposJP0HQh28LCwXqWgE51Ysy94LkS4ON5F9p1Orp9ue1K5@/iGug79PZ1R1ivD7H20BnaQ2PIz42HvnWdA/hxwg2X3IQ6YD0Y4lG28XjpiHuUnpZjWe9CTxSNXFA6Tn8lTvv48iu@ufVecOd6ByL8x62Ld/qEyw50rO01Q2MK45LnTJyxIZFvXVILF3r4fZ0MDTapf94VpBvn@UCR4Pnzwr91bjnQncl4TI/22Jp6dKOsEr2zfJve1OdHU@hQpOMO5NfOqCP7gbJ/boW2wFeLmI456Q7xpXHO2cbA6XSH5m1Idwx9YpsnSrDkw73vNHdFyphMuo/BsmUCed25jPxSi8Yf4eNgXaP7q0d8WAsdN@grq1bo6LVsaayfdD2@GoouVsEF4Uhv5C9vV@j198qrqTlZAI2cZQqXd/m2BDrW4e6fnlirWdE7Egsx7J@qWMulpKSjQi4ZGVB41HXFLp9zi3SxbJbf1iEUrSVhFDmX8j7k9s/@0OqgGVm3hfAl/lo6tLRykLOH04F3XWDy5foeqGh4W79sQWeZI0vWMGbptv9YR2bNUvAlR3i2QeeaGjfuqeRv3FShdKol6Y4JjzY8oOmma9fQLHPs8TuT@mu34vyzTDAXv7pfyGkzXz2Z9humZ/T5Fgi6blMRR46LJ5FBB5G6uJOOK@gozLnixQWX7QxAqEsWWyQO0q5TW1YeE1rd/OGYKX3xqTHQ8az1I3OChzVXcAWx7KrjRbfC/vpU98yvT6Fm65gNLTbwbUg3@mo/@lbAe6wPzO7DpYYIkfQJ7J/05I8l9seg621xNjQ9PNEUOm5YmEKW40yMXNeGecOKlFfX7UNjFYsOxF@DXJl61dq6M57j22Jzct20rG5OaJXVf66bOq47BHYjEmfT0Xjq@Y/VONCZqegq9OiEwr0zE4BLr0C0sqFuTVavVEeWXEEL8wfFhXOdNv6laTkD9mUpw0BpAyUMlfMVjHMPhucneCDHtVdwIpX9jtueuNAhubxir6BtjSyTTNuc3LyaM5ng4ZzgiZXhIwe@oaA8wrt8930hSMerKfLodl1/8WryLeM7cN6RM3W7BjpDeyPRaYFfqrEXnD7GNzoctJdyFp2ldR0Luhc4rJVdpuvY04nkTu0bR4XCjaNChc1KhQgbsMTX9x8/S0a5gU5r36aFGjD5m3rWfOFae2DgCpOZNihi6@XocupgLnGf20l6SkeFb8mzi8acuiSu7zur5jtP5jCAvPOECYT/dHTf6OK24a1lf@o8dmwHRqMxCMrRU4O/87900GN1Rsz2CN9qB/r0bi3miMCuGYS4tqGPjQ60r7VwvctYxAHf1yf6mqGI1gZp/he6buUV0@oY7kta9Iu4101plxF6aMxobrGeYXgflCbdLleJcT1uqY8s7dh4Y8ex@Z2kbQYe6uObpQoMBXR7941yGQ/iL60LrJyfLVf18JSfEjF63CjFurq6Rsex@P2GM0m2yc8E6K5peMojtHFAYYUck0D78m6UIcUbZchiagSa7Knu0Sb96qnGAqQ6e48jQEPd7Tq4E@Y7bjidEzFMcIuYDs/284MDHSD8DCSW3p36FhhvQ8sadUZ0WzthiLTmU6ODbwV1yJrHRJ9db0y@MuSbMoic6AoNAATiCjt1gSWewGwkefuwtTSPWqaqOaYbSeq12@V0WEeyTaP7WsdVM4fotVibXoqHOiufknPNWnWkG9EqsqLTm@4re9Ly0TVQaCxDmgxdmPMrk5uWtwMzKyv2Q6YjAzeZl3dh1qqujjekyjqr99ND4eoakm/rD2RJaPeP64fS7lrNE8HD/@G9jxUYhNuFXGB6BETX7Tv4gPzUtf3Hu3DgE8eb9M3ZIeCNbwGsEydYrTxkgQfvGejaWlcJaD17avHVh0Hk3NWoR9MxiUzbSpJF4npiSIZ9KpEhuNn1Gjn8pS9lF02iToye5NtBwJ0G6VHw/leYzH@u2ECNykY87KkqnLCzQs4//rmKuGeBZAB9y5lIY4@eyth7cvDo8Fgee@rK8Wl3iG9HXNPjlgwraKVMZEnqpe5G9jv5cbSe6U2Ue0eqtPfoQMYEa@jNdzQkeODO3NJj7bqnb29UV/S1syCMNSarFcSHx48fpRavaLLE3tB1RkYyGr13dJTGN00@PloZHc39AHpH35mtzX6wr6rJFez7zKbdwXXSc0VJ6yAdGzAbBWZ8yO2y3KpcdZ2x0Tuej43PYPBECe69Y/GFtZX8VD81B9gLWXktoaijsrJcyCUjJ7Nhsm244XNde56YY5SWXXoo/LH2OApqDlnFza7WHm7a8b@qxbCMfxLh/TKpmevcOjEl6BmDIboU3fv7Iqaq6jo6H@l9aFeWX9tYywlW7Q9bzuk7bCUb/uRFCoOkCXCVZN56jrwojUB0K3jD5Xk/EJydtcdgbgIQBhdWdvgzw57rtkR7WTepFxXIjYfabkzypfEOG1LhCZ9TtAC9co8vPFLPEl1yJm8p@NiNZNnbu3dwW4anPi1vTvXRp8/YE91DIyQ3J4xibLwDxgvN6KWE61ZoAW/tdmrPBVDajfAG49X9ucKOdLfn2PPZ7Ztw9A4qDu1kXDiEhT5KZFjmzFw1VnX5utaT1ceMbiubv8ThzJf04KhxGh/Q22//M1XNZMj0ED7VDPfe0jJBB2cJdOlztGcXjTo@CEVDF/UWGQKSK2ejj4wZHkfhq8GrJvUrx7fCDWNfMbl@OLkprnRDXO6G8q7FYSDLyhn1BoD5G@JYXg6jHznW2dCR93TX8FacP16J0E0VKd9QkXJEOr8uZXARlDYWffd6FR9fXfAfK7n12Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lXXY7aORSfYYjaVfj/ePU@guHW8ZOP4rH9y/uryzqbGyoMf669URJGlOVkaBEDSGU3ol4nr08gZpB3Rewx6Y3L4iu@dM9sl3w8QsfON59VkEc3x/Ol6PMchGtPN/VZwvJfwc5szOmcfu4atxCzV9xdwfz8etDl@n07JwYRDNjD483g246/BI0SIlLrD44slSML48Ojk8ioS5xmy2btIrzdbNIVfGLEr99Di3VOx2/fnpCmKtf98I1A2Qx@FzrR7Ehd3HR9dFAk7fhpORFcR8rNuLFdOlBus5E3rTcGXkk/mMjlGubOkhP8W2Ks7trghemtjDgGyaULantNtoWb/dXseVx8YXtPcAahCbcLWEA/UNLxmz3DDAkLKs7ajOyUL5WUL3aDw07dnKqNG6PHSKNPHSW90NdtmR5ZyxR6FVoatp@FugACRqQdxL@zZg@FvT/F1VTw7MvCcSdiqVTC5/qCT64i3a2U1sop3JTXrJFtJeXLAN/8VWiBCDV2X9V3nRHB1MtA18F1cgEJPaJhRTq6n5MtvBL4NUQI1OUokYREa/grIabPPcf0u1UlEv2UaNiRWR@e8JhzZ8uR1agIsWNKFOTDpR2eYEYjaDd1wZfVKBXTCamsNcQM1nwCcr0bf9q/5bwIDS5vmTgyf7R8e7x8@OGpnWpf@WcFAJ24bSAlsEH2Z7ItTdJxsM@dwqNb2dbkFx9LkHnNJ7Qb0Y1OxK1WpLVVtUStzBPJvntq0o9KK0Il0CfpLIS6NYZFwI4rCDGlP7@O/IV/g7y/TqNTQRBy1SmdBmFZZZVfBYh@Fr0/bjr37GhmLxM0cV/NARFuwbEgZGHDhOzy/RM9jtV1Dig92DR8@e7rMAwQXTnJm9ybBWznM709x4A7RT36STYzUW97PEoa1qtfiDOBAmLsdZhV5tJxvPwOeQLKAOvhTv595iiU2CDxSMh42i/OdvKJdxGQ9BJyFtPEAqDsUCyxOjbGxssGNgEnb/6cFn@08Z4r9/n4KRRAiCHeN7tX/24x7/SkJg9yb4xJM7orGG7IYI0XfrgxfOF@/EI82p647Xf@iJvkpAb56Hn0MIv@ciCPS1DODbMzJZd8WcWZIsDPEPU/nW5oKCiIUCy@q43o6W41yPnZqeie@9Iw59NOS2zOx4RIeMF8psF79ihd/K0umTHYD61J5wY0m@yZQYcJocipw02yRk@Qc@xEjC@PYGMHvHADWEebYJg9qkwl4CJ@KadoXbRZCkevxalgB0hVwSDl2RhNcsv3lK01Xe/to/UQZVBu4JuL/ju2eZe@D7Fd/XB/evcvdzBRntuqW4BS5RhNC6o18DjkhIf6R95ONdNrdFsSAcGrQL5CozR9BMp0R1TM5L4HcJxPECTqLxGTQasBu0mG@DgpdnuK0EmpesKAqyFKrGMr0BYMz4cbwrZiYL@UJOVQBJ6TQASHbhB/ieMQeYTFagmwin5rj2AtSt7e1tJuL82KgVqrxllU37eVZ8ESK6CWmFsyEi12CQB7IsckBc3c8Gg09KTWJWlF5xNY6Cq@fAqETxOHqh3/YJIbIEEIvTyEBD4zP8ztvEnQfmUjv4ZbTIN0M2fUCSCmMSuZKi4Ftv@NSZAPtAJ118FYhbb8DjqHwERDuEHv/6IVkpRX6Ur/esxUvHwcdJ/L4mowzgoLKZq4NptG3FzxHEEYKoiKvYt/GcNSdNu6Vw3mTApj9cwcw2uH9ZGazhWV7v3es2KhNXLUwisdjdI9vBhYAHUBmW0BQtq6iF5KJKudzKKvk18ouB6qAhnAsoDsQUiIyuYb50xt7u3v7Bx4dPjq7ZYaSU8avJQO7Xt1NNSU43WqEjHq3WcpPce6AcPb73IGiIBdKFiDQGwe/XRL2pJov1PQS5eF/katVWYXi1dusx/py/UX4V36x2E2qU6RoeauY9yqUz29IDevPqauFaaRW18vmbUFrAUyKg9/hrs9dQTSTPLxut7XrTjsWvc8KKjvA8Jm9hJwBX09vaVJDZr1cOKxZ@l/QYP07mRftidnVfFDezaOYL39qfOCcLQ2h@QCQiUt@gGBCRgqwESdf2vkOuoy/M9Wn8u6ncPljU@lEE4ULmJopHQB0Hn2BFKbIwNurb2RzCBNIyO0JgdYrb2wzMAoamNrnFqERS8D9ZwQtO@B9lnVVmMh3QSiRR2hGsNLvJdGcALylAh0bt7skU5khPnDE3YU4b8feNwPXUAfF7f8on7gb7eDqCdH16PDVoUwQktwSZgZLxEFWuS4GU8C13zlJoGxXKa6D9Tr/i8qiXT8yS8tCY9cwByPZEMg0S7UNVbbHQuidWmqx52nGR2mzRCjd2xY/wZego2d/LxOtsgYDe0GXT7hmzRPwsnqy0oHwMj599fhpPiqt4iUzN@rZXe1dtzoboF9WbJYk@8XtnYNB1lbQol69LCQi7CpjbPgu@n1Quy0NPoO/h1VBzP5q4j8AJakSiP9LHLDG1ud04mZE30UzYaTKoJdW5TUqbpVI0oYIHRciMcvbJxcfvhG7PWUKpARNgqGf38PHaHLOGKsstcFMhSbaJ3zXbA40LLSkmBZgDQ5YKga0hC8E0AzDinUTmDA55MB7SwoOs762Ips880dqxgzShWrP6HRb5Tt2y5iiWyxW/QZelYpkB910Xh7ICYK/JuUCvB@r6JmWAZjD9lYXYQpBfl3gxKjfGEXno26IBdGIRO7KBiRoGsBZWXrtDF3@JfRv6CugHlcqz4wftUlIRWWjTZuCaPdzb4KbQwyme//Ea6KbKUtJ4lc/oPsJsaD2wzY3moBG7B9RhxCsiNRYlw9VPTS94U1Vv5Ho/o98KkDKHA4D/7l87AIcWH4PFqBVxq4X9z36GH7MWE5uqetJ2T1PxfKYKN7WaZ3n24WZTkjYbmdrdTR1mUZNXsybMyZWt3P1TY9jvHQyUpiiyLMspytb5efzB1hPzuVZ4NbvMqqVXJ2O10JBfzVpiqZY@abEnT754036TFGen81diM6HRR5X3Di9ENYcT/VilzM53CtnYSRm/Tcp0PX/CZjBvZSfsNVwnfYb/5H7di7h1dHf6r@mbTnGRxZpN/BK1WBQVpRFvwT9N91/AxSf@jbpcl3dab94kG7o@mc2ZaZpjr9eDnzMEDVJLHjEo9w5IekqvsCY9aQJF12jWX6wj6Hm41TV8EVS@28YQMkQ52zUGg@m@PjenDyaPv/w8uJ7h9frpigWJViqVkKTG1eBKW8/HmJbR/uwnG5fp8yft7T/75kgxNvBxiI/vXD5G95Ga/3Bj48N793K5tKZp3P3kyye/uLu7m7ufzj9p5HdyUmZj@0//ZGND07Y1ZaPleWor3jg5@ULUMjlR/rMfxdtPnnzd8@rZ//Mbb@oq3opwO2VFkBNwZZkKTryX4KeijvWuV@x1DLhcjc3prx0Lws83mFrfKf6X7x2@ik1idU353IXnJPYqVijFuBMc4MsGvtNYPbaNyQqXsblSq9XAWfwv/xby1z8GOBgz34ZbPR/AKsxjdalGWS5i9QI4VE2Dcv/vb3wjgiEXEzVS44LrLmvAJeaKmrjTgmuLrm0BbQVKGUUJ0tmT4cRwmFq6o95BjwkeeNgGGl03Js0YfumXHd5l7GkjlUq15LYEl/wc14gUVdWaqnoHpIH04VatJm0xbgwxm83fQYPOSVrRGjgwYBp32Of/EFdsVWD15wb3VIgVNu6@uF@vQ6Wy9exWPUWX35OoUxVLouPcFVmavYjDFKTRevGI9xxWFzMlTUyn07w7zZBU0mzBSXjxeywWhmCXZVfDlrJAEj809v7pYvt4/fn/9uff//Pv0d/36fcf0Jii3TP7yhYkOoUuUYfrbqXSrdfFuiueN9FfBz7KVEqVktK@bCa2QAK1njI189FFPJ@NHzEU/zAAsGaScsNFxdb94tFfjy2C6zykHg3zI3hiCmB@LcixRDVyh1S7lg6GVv/YqdQ4rbckVIhqUkMt5FsSzxVgWS@zxl1oJlErlsVWXctrh9B0qsgbbrjpMScGM8NCQEcf3/qibvUwZuGrR4Ni9SBbfZHmfdMF6NaFWKOhtAwaEIIwdnejslGqFCqa0g4Dr1@sej3IMIwnXuw0Fl6cOrEFQWMha14NC5oi9LCAg9n7pAPNKCLBZuEVcV692jyBm3XyTsm5lpLW9@HagD/6hyv04n2DQvxgSnL92mAVdUvLKvkPC/sae79LgHGCdTudzutuB9UAvaN3dXWiT/WZPtcnnWln1pl0p6yLn3lHfJksxbJ5dTN2Z02tianfNDbYUy6FWiwVXM3UrdczWW77TnI4@JMkZxYTYv8AV13VVLYF41MGbqCUkRPmzPinqgKLncPVerPVeLMFHbSe2ibp2KpLPpbwkNt3Wynp8rIB7mrV/9@uh84qXdwFlWtdplLbz@ugejyvN1IA8rkPUpYYAZXb9dY2xYSF@aX50dstUF6k1HZju@bs0Q@ywCXFc0684NxtAeDtJWTv3k3J4LoLAOqb0B@TqdSmJG3g2NjwxwpI3KqnglohDgnQFs7Pf84fTPSgy15uX9YvG9uXl9vb8L9N90v/CaGX29f@6bG41qRZxLdQtDQbSr2pNH1B0QK/rNQxRFaa4KjDE9I1slqp1UAHXHLrv81/Ob24hyGIcksGrIXYFtuKoWm/bGxLiL14@9X/gr/m269@H/VFBn9GRYidY7dWtnC2WeaTTrgx@7HNHvPLBjf@Ai@GYMDjOgba/GbjhpSivJBZha/5J9RSISnjANx2@m20FiCzF5AUFTcYl5iolQpiO6XONRbbFgtFGpl@4doVj8f/0QutXIzz5Rl8yf2F53mPI7gtsIPEVS2jSupFndtx55/c@IVV1z/6hXWXELsoM6MCVOl6jNNDiAH7xCQJRqn69ggPQeP@iIRT0dPaF9KzXQnXTvQJ7X51@bpA7WC/Vi7X@dbO5hPqKlv3t@Cuwv/@BtSCNfuQttmvdUeg9Tb72bzWRJvfManzCv8evcY/dtzFv6ev8I8dv8a/pxP8Y487@Hf8Cv92O/h3PMK/e6/w7/Fr/Hs2wL/m17JZtSpunhNhUmpZvdyciUSgamyn3vzaxJ1XLMNumL2W/zmbbK7MkrHm14wZftS8wgP78Z9@95vfjNdqcSlOHwnJqY7L1GQVaA818uLVu3EhVmOb6qaasTLdjNpRO@AwWcZlmWFmqPZgctJWWcZgmXlmzjIjR@2By4C/DLjMTJ9lBixjZ2xICLHgmrQzE3T14TGAvz4AcuHPxDN9HTXTZVCQhYoafV8QwYProt0UGizOxBcGzC9lVc7IBbOFX2VpiC9eNJWtllYuMRlZSm43XjTjLTTTrZVzrDM3Npov2izmwQy1GlOaTYXTBKpLJLu8bLf3P73fbis4zjQfO4eL/8PDUdR74//o0Hl86Iwc@D88PIS@YdRTd1Mgge/erYFE9h87sXp1p1khuR7I9piyvdOsZyV0F1IgrjUMS73ntYAIz/pGU4ifJXBycYbzi@rnZ9XTKrnPAi842tVFgiAZd/hPuM5gDAvmG2dwnZ6hg3zoPPu8Gbq4Q/n8DII@ZzCzCv9hBhf1/lf4N//b@n/8jCVZotFKJs4vtxN0JfEvmTy/PL/07/VkIuF7EtvwhwHgxyznl3V0UqJzcDUSyVby8pKHwT2R3OYA61DMdp3yLtKB3I@FRVKx/Jb4r/uEov2rGa8ykDg0e85nqB/FxCrTFwdnms1ZJpOsdoIvDuA2sH5BpxOSVfrc3Ganobb@9Ef0VYmdJCXK56pVdYtxj5bTqtVc4CuWqtVS4NlMJMrXr3pmRy3ABCOXSyarVfDsBGAz4IW8DfYmxWqsCffWnTu8kJJ2cRHAzOYKqYyawdxBSXko1vD0ri9dzw8O6YMMIFryMfwSChcliQx9zgU/GRYXK@KdOwn/U@Q7u8k7d7Ry5uIiDBmPIUhdCmq3e6bbbmN49uJCbIt00KWcB3@mdHGhZsopNZ503MSn@K05KCohqexDrU6llkFma7kiRPsI5Le3C7l6vZCDkEIpnsRN8wai3wJ842K8KsbOqQ5qqcgloFjF4OgBIOjLOAKw88sYNSjL5ZMJEKVJUPIuY/jnik3RH1vy@SRQ5lLkKdVymSdNslwhUUqV/b/aBky7QYvhf6iKZVO5reLWXVBq8c9bOadAmVw9N2rqZe3cqOCy@WW163@1F40aGHfuZMtAolKm2hTa7fu7x7vtdk0URdSE4IaBJN0FtPXgxhtU83y5xSlSqd6lZlZLeQbtydNIcRghWAmIrmhbebWERBLMPtosAZIIKtFog20IGj3xJpQ55TYgEOYrUHgPLtZjHTbAiw1w9ZOZzKKLWYzH073bDRM5/PJjQy/lxSsMMcJL8HthlrMojNhPHu3u7R@ntW2JxbQHu3tp7ejZvZiK3vzCT9FZ9D/d371/@AwyPHm0v3u0/9HBZ/vPnkC4x84WVyD0/fviGXWt8J@xz4WX7mvdMHRjahjts@n07BV7aZptExrTmkKlnIHLPKMNdRnri3pV4dc1Pf3lS90d08Xe/vDbb3/43739ne@@/Z1vv/2d7//0q@9/G34/ht93@fO7/6acx/tPv/pnv/v2t38HAv8D/P4Ifj/56Ve/8Q3@I/8fw@8/RcL@2P9F0vGfALB@5adffe9HP/3qV38Av3/p/35w/fdrP1n9@/631v8w3/d@9@Y03/238Ps9DitI@93f5mH4vJb@t3m6X/3B23/x7/j/n/p/6Pydt//ij/Hme/7pD/70P7395r/XtNKf/uu33/re22998@23vvP2W/9Ye/sb/1rNRG@/@/b7f/BXf/h7f/WH/yP9/5juv/cu/29/8E//4n/9i//9L/7Q//0Efv8OXD/5i38PXeVv/@CH@P@9P/jbP/oh/v/P/@pv/@DX//ZX/idy/CZ3/D//8t/w@1//2n/8m9/6zl/95Bt/8@s/@Zvf/IO/@j9@9f/6jf/41//97//1P/kmBv7mT/7qj37lL7/57b/81j//y29@teb@7RvvX71D@Ff/ACHvjue7wHmXer1vyFc/Fz5/H2osSgE@Ae7@5be/8UvA4P@Csbff/jG@DgS/Nf8/1lRK82Pu@/@AQ7teZ4zJgAt@v/72299FEv0PQCL4D@n1ndCzFMM931l4gKy/tSLTL//0q3/@I/LFjEqdtmVw7C5ppdQWzG@2ymV//PZ3bCDLLy1DCwH4JX0HJdRS3HdQtr394Tfe/ugfv/3hb7794a/g4C3lyundtKTest0FCfPvkA4TFt4lHSb8AstP0RqalPoCfOwLP/KLL74Q2hcKvnd29wJCv6AgfjEehe@l@VFBHIbji2rsgkXdvjPjOzf90LBkxhovXrRwQxXCsPQU6R5bgWqUz7JZKliSZrNgaRoTzbb4KjXjK7czip4JeFv8L5wzgaUWi9n4nbxwSZdK4sn8IrhTyEMxqdkssiZOeg9hyENoI5jKzZUZ1mA2S81gEgwOKCEFUfdAHa/VUpixxvEBL0etXmKESipVg3pjbp4n3S4hiNk9ggI5a6mnrL1Vm/GMKYRXD8iREjDoqahqYqpUuw8F1mb3GcJC4AT2xYtavVSb1RHcG06P1Cx1j3BCYLXUrP4G/DWCCfmE2P03gEqplkrVS1ggVpI3T7rNGylPlaO6p1jKbwN44nn@nbuMfSiqJbHNFUYkGE@N99QiNSaE5BDfTG351aH/wEm/LSL4BhXll8J4/A7ppjtcXcUEAFeSZFlm8MMd9h12F6JnHFSKioVHikNIEUcQB4QBDBeDUkKK2jdFHig/Vtt67wuBYWU2NzeFWF3MiocykU5RmHtSoZcb8LwfTi8qTCyURQw26E2PABfIX6XyN@O4cxZnHDD7MMV/d@9usQ@hmvRchAlMSmWdnBPjULZTKVED@HUnJTyHaYkAfEqALgR5VqOdupSQTjMm12IYxw4PD30kKOB5TUgBm2tZFf24XzSdTmOQQ5bTcjrtP2V6UoDsO2SK9Z/yJhKXPsbMNC1XhdlTlWEQi051VJgCY@CbN2@gVegAVeUAJp/MP0ul5UoUCQHc/IZlzYM3grRcWeAzc6YWcowlaDUVriRLCizBtpICP3bPkQiuRFwrleKUDqgvJ7aCo3UFldgBV1JjdUQ0uPiUsJRPBpF7h2zv8PHj/U@Px60WEwz6uLTRHrtO1/C8BMbtfnqfv3KhlQvJWKOBoI8rGgoYYb@SIWF8cP/pwVGF8Ur7TZAgxKq0cepXs6wKsfH48@2Yf7RIxO@jOeIR3iuLuiW0chayxupCrGvgzAJ3xKt0pKQqPPYG95wZzOnTophWCzizS9L6MRN@0ZkytN7JTX1An8IXMeTtbaKAUD@XaG8CndBaBaFe9w/lMVWoH@0fQ4bjQ6ZqGVmof8FmMhYoXQp1q2YZ9mAy3MTTbWIzI0bqtNnIpPFPy2bhruYKaTVfbG1sWOcSltmkZjvHY4qX4D2XsBofwMWEDwT2AQTBBWXg2UPmH/w8OKz6p@/QTlaCH8ET1Tx0s6SAi9YcnDCOXlXg7uWdHiG28eWXE1avw/xaOnggxEBaDFlwAE0ye/JQpmbuTV2DYgeM9czPTPzwndwzvbGlz6HrADVil5eXfYB08IBpdY28PEcP75ddCumA@3KmCzG7Uqm9UXNFQTupVN5kNU2AAGFLwRNuG8AAdFBgS@F/VQ8KyWZLCkgqVRThkc1mBVwoFoSKITA6DfImU6tJnAezOZUOgwj4LQV9VtPCy087@3CRNpvhaTEGIthg4rJMEFfkcb6vIJAPiIbH3@jLvVW/c2bu3MniIkY2lwlXK6jG7BLaZjObyyLFhf//Ci7avdke17MZdVsZg1MHZ25b0cHZAWd@W@mA0wRneVsxwTmtZ9XMtjKtC0zY5sYyGdriqIkTY4a2eXmYWPcMqy/j@0M1kQrQxG3f@HQ9yFjv1XpOl768Xe3JJn4BHd@c5RlyObHq2GjGrYYGHehdY5ZInguD2hm93ysYtYGMlkFcW7eEntxxenPZm8wtfBPHctxaHDTCeBCxgG6AKoLLXzvZbK7SYC157Ix3BC1fTDXUDIwh@FNLaS29YewUi5We3LUM3d3JV/KldA9f8vG3tHbymcpA/uLxo4eTyfipQW/@7OTKkAFtaaHVm51SJZ9vNRqimGpQMS38bjCXUNLGBnRrQ@9J8MQNL0/SSi3I3DPdWi0e38mqmqRWspnSpbAgHNIca1gXMGsKa5ZGup/7QqBiOzbIm0paT5vnRIVKv9@/3DpPLTyCfi5xH9DnUtLTnfPQW5Ui6SpsmpbMRSSE6H0g97m/l1cRtXxJrDaqC3@xIFZbl8LdkdEzdXzhp5k5v56rAHKZQ41BQU0mXFZcx5lUOkbfcY1FwqxaCBJyhK4nyImXYXHNDJZ4fr24QiTR7Pw6lFxevAxzBWgJl5dAd05s6BfcEGqdzsU21HKutQ9CqNHaDkykYtvEnj/X9XodGvk8V9Ry@VxeyxYK@aIGg005V8iXoJtlCpm8pgGAXLlULl4CR7@J0bfP2N55wOcVtP6e0CvcemGjlXzzqWmdl7ISLz6RrF5ext4IMV2X6rWslhU0TdKyUlaV1Cz@3@LQ8P/d02vwr@EdcmU14Rjtk3wKox@M2DZ7hHYOJg47dvBLNwN2z@iuSbE31Onk8Z7reN7fI8093T7hUfdNbhQ0jHqo4@e@vJE5Ga5J8Ww8QtMmhvsPBmF/1AEEUaTxBPfg5lqOsypBkT17sqaWj0Mz3EAMbocbkj89@OjhceR5vL@791AosHuHn96/8sj7ifLs0f6D49Bb5LFB1nwI4hf3Hz266vUfucNnT/tTx8Wf8ODwWW5xC4PwxVYhB9dyojCYgPg39JJ@CIoBzKfyxcChCvg6xB2Y497xnfnCwplB5@f8rV3TC4/n8xe4K8Jx8CqvzlBadgzW5RZscNJN1uV8lVwtlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlo7fLu9vQOBQx9cSDdRLLQs5EYs@c1yrd2b2jA3hMb4BWVbxO9GIhPAQgIymXbJMADoJ2irt4VfFcXepY00NNh2ztYHwwCB0uuZgCOPomRMkEDq6zuD3vhfkN6LX5OaACS@Dwq7FWNeTCzFBFPdE8aE@0WOlRtVrjeuZSuXOHfWJK5azojcw9mfAsewZ9CDdnadL4kQWH7D2APcmrILqjOt6HaYSDVC8yxqMvjs5zaiXMvnsX//Wj//uT359UFO3mpm9zPbO40f5CshUUEYZ6Zu@TirT7EQrl/KlclYrpUvlUi6vFvL5tKqlYWJXLINun1FLaqGUL6vpUq4MmkSuDLH5ctHXaJVAhVW2KgDW7uJ3i7dpgiMPYSbDdxPZ64SeZDE99E@ZaEAeUcC55IRe8d4yazAIMjXDskUGEHXWZbEHD/YyDx6I4j304NGLvYwo9tCTL2UyxXuiaFDMXgm1ItHheUpoAU6ccE8mcw@oPOUA0Hi6KA7Rs1/AVTFRNNGzt/vgAZbTR4@G@SHZCY/hHivwFCGZjR5QtAnAqxAaJNvl5eQI0X30YJEY84DH7EGcKH4UoIMxT3kyDuBhUNPdXVE84J7dXYzZo2rnOaKfoGeXLlF0wQOsL4oDcAxc6HSi2AEndgBR7IKrO9chDL8Rjfa17YkuinNOHiSQKM4otd49EcV2EI7FfOZjk0fqVsij8lrfJU8Z/0RRC5DGZNnQkxXFXOjJQd0ePvxMH056xoBfc5c/u1DThw@zujmb7j/ofPRRZzDouPPd/Y@eYtTe3kPQKOZTtzPo@Bk7bbgcyLX3UNNPRvOrF9T6oN2u6NbKqE/a7ZxuX4lqz9sGYgi5XgFm/jXAgkbtPYjae9i@q6/aDSaAbez7I3h28Lo3guc9vcOjgoui6DnrdMQqsr@iNBMC6vy4j4vd8QRkqZ0e6V3XqaJ/VmOZNK4OzBuFTKtKEWwEunumeonx/QTedVzCSZ7PG7NaplWb1YoaP07UT4jNmZY3xfTGaEct5ysb@o6q5VKzClqZcPpxFpfUHZZQ72y9ZolPkzsa6PFic2dHEhtqa0dTS5VC8fnWVBSTFbzvZIsVSJiJZxjDW7JRbO0U85EsxWJKV7RKsQiKFRBlAiN6B5dW2onEmaGfJJOILk70oQpUVzaneprVfmKWntU4XmyerM5qapXblWWZa7B6aMR82p04Loc4AHCznUwFN9ITolouiVC@oiSSyVDowbRbWBzV/PzrxyfHx19AHBPq/hLEE/7V9arv/ejhnnxwGPjQ/Lj8ALVKx5X3UGotxXD9Mgg6hnmE/BAGUZiTBWH4Np/rWPI@nXYD1TSICAzqyL4pUPn44RKco6FzxktGYwhVsidndw2G1tnNHtNrdXDpPZYgrJiePKPhu12v19q1EdkLgCoGuT5hZLp8AebA47iHJhoo@zm@4eZHtGuZy2qnNovNAE67xiT1xcjpvdBS3WoPjbLfq93DzNU2PDtVo2a4ruOKMbHa37FrjE1tT@8bTwwXjY8cHG6CMoGvvSX6zEhusuY@pt7D2calVHeZvcDs0@koAWp5J7kcFPEiaRJfD6p8Tu9h4kGLy2q/xhLPk9VX4HU3WaIn30vu5Kq9xD3WTkJI5kX/RZ9prJCr0owhgZCgGxFtsM56slb/BPQfDvikUgFE/DY@AZhYEoA1exShJ8fmZbVbs1hCYjOWJPLkqoNaA3Nf4G1bEsWWJDUuWkJdkj4X6tBTq/OYXvOmHfqSB8t0VC1TqM4gTC3mqkNoWP35rOrWxlPXqFrg9dfj@OumehXICVQDMK8vEm9/6RvJbSlf42FVAnVhgcrRltu1WdVG24DAErVsDSJSjVwmDTNwuBXTMNprhbRaSGfTubRUxFAY6tP5NATC7AZ0i4SVEBkT05lZRlbTqqGmE5kXZu9FMn2SAIWFSMaS6Ymzb09HDEKgkZAryQtPnSVT2pbFoBUcpm9LxKYgK6pYMaD5kI3N9BBBPTV0i3IkkxLLbiWszQSm2TyejvcbrUplfzb@OkQlpFc7hVQxk3qdTFYTG8maZ7wS6lWhjnKFaj3eAJ71lyqZNx01oI3BpRa1SqPRwSoWM@lsJgu1M9sXg22xLrbSmY2CCk10yUhgMC4xoqt3qOsswsZt1LotA5pOLWtVQaaltGxJk8pKfiuf4ct5PKcw9gUbUpIlmmLwanUiHi9q8XgyXsWNhA3RXzkGaUaSLA5iNX5H3RFBDRMrYlnDBAuhSG/PZgLsQBG7FHDxguXKQuxcuDy/3K4LXxOO8J3Ibe05/hWfP949xL@vQVAZvKXnj58dPjt8IDCFzmrK7Vh1oypX21XwSHL9rhCrMAYytOnbfVI2GHvfU6Cp7fpz/mzi@X6AK5C9X9BZ6XSWYeKMjX2GNgV2WBzqoLujhqZlWw2tCKMeyNEgKcz3q7jNEsM3COQ6NIZ3Dvhtp@r4Ot4nbD7XU1Kw7n@HsUFqUyDyxK5uqe7WdgdPd4MDZrt7qzdeN2cKrjE3QVfHA2mx83gsfgl/QuwuvRyo8ZcDWSx8PRC3Rv1djWyuwJLlYNPha/G7sXg8jqv7Fea9iVG7Ba9bffJCA5aJ2U4QALMlXI2CwSyfxyXwmPJi7H2plbKPDw7t@@4Dg/G3r0q5tliPsYwq4UtM1YofmhfbGycqcExWzJ6kY@xujI7Ci@WSJmo8oBpjJ1JcraTT0MjNjYsNBzc3WHjk7o398dcZG8ezuThjzVpsVsv5B7fVel1StzU0plZkFZD9fbUgZS7qnMfrFFHQIObtL/0gN9sugV/LqODXtHxKq9fVLY0lY@O3X/0@2sU53/9s9xGL45L43/3Jj7Ti3/3Jv6JTY/FLWibXssUYpESnWijGzs/H5@eXcPG4fKwV40jliklw8y0bNVZXVC1r23aVVRRd3yqmctpdu6r4adWimox5UszffCrmY96FH6VlShAV7A5RkFjAFojtPzXzmnp3eweqs5PNadUNaH81fDmUhX/bhleG1i09fnHBGHi69d5gYGrkUhRWeSOx7TfSNnuDOzNvpA32olbHHX4VXykNdi628BU73L2L11PKVpzB1IjVG5fVy1aKtj5gCvncMLbs5hWGbW7gOxbLQVs2/BlbHv1hpiDAA2/gM7ZeemJiK6kovV5ofG3bYPk6cMWWArhtBdsX/E@Smsm3v/Qbmlb4uz/5tYv2RfsLDSaT5XJB1WI/@9n21J56Rq/@M8h4g8GTYEJIez9omQQd4USScdOlpp8rdMhdmMNObVSaefpgWokTSVQ4zIFt9GhaKZyikkQN2eY293oJSraF9hDSpHSTjatkVRBC5ZSUanfQTRMMtoUmLRutpHAufIBRMBIzUMyrwgcLUBAwgrHX6bY9a@qO6Y2UBOVTW2l2B7JACR@gOcMNsuPgi3EJ5JmydT0rR9kjqpFCxUaG56FxRBiBhA8gi2/315qzsY4mRzClacO4IWMSwpMieg0ouwVlWzxDm0ITVHueIM04djyTDYq38AFoEkQFExQMZm5DgipIoQ@AAFCHhA/YbLFtlk2yczOVqi4sL17i0Xq0DakH5g4EzIbQemheI8hcxXQQBAo/fmkS@cJvYdDtIoEBEA6D78TXYMqA2cmHGhvZI3lnUACLbH8lqGrszp0FVrWa2UsyqhHCPzHHuOBF7WCvxhWABdOtD3sVMc3QpmU1CA3ZDiieInSB6yRuzLIaycpE9F4KAvy/M9MiR15pKoqoYgX89uK9ogskg8xIdt6GXbZdY6pWTLIQ@S7g3iWk6K3zcA7ZnH0oa18EkZeA4c9iwXdcQEQdRxcRfb69au@CgZY9xY9ooNUzLgx8OxXcrhmKuoNJkDvMBVUxLUrdN12Y3dARgcCkYiKrJjHbwgQl4UGH37UcwzPo@SQ@KBemZvDU0TSgX84GmTTqOtCg3tixyZYg2TrCFwCAI0BG@WbYONpT@ww/uuS3DWWOYuSRCTbkfMSYbCPS16opL@7Rd1yYBAe0STNjILPuqMe0MksQo5G5ODsEl6RMhHAHVGWkcccyRoDSkWHQK2JeRVEGoD5NO2Qz77EJfDV8YMJ4Y3uK/2Fw5cw8MZVj/GiE5PTxTTJugSSGGhd2P34cwLdPZznOCbPME4OvDSeW7Ld4DCYLoO@mgbKLHxC2gudMtGwaVyvUNE8FvyI8itxZSkfybiTmyevPrLqRaGOLXtDgY7r40e9T3Y7Ql64LwZ8fe3MvsABFdozAL4ci1/Btv9TiaNUhNGok@LasamRGScY9h3ECZquBDSh0CmPXOGU40xVwjAGh2Q2sqWAvhtp@QAMA9T3oWWgacuJW0AYQYOL2El3oer6At9mHLKsJmJAb6PKNaQEMbPraMnSIg6xYD2/Sg4aRaaEd5Qr0zlEP4tD6hM9@mD/gbnST2c4Fe7MNHxwOOlRWjfFuEXjyEQ/2DuRnqvoGRBYAwxWYbCTEFIBNiUmRgw7zX83OuV0gWVJh1yGlGULwSQ1QSFXQUeTQN9oXX0cSIOKe7nET@r7hyLOzM5msmU5dUzY8/GKQ59i6pYwHJijQjjIxRmP/26wmfpPbh7twSfxDYfJ4ON6ZoepaK9@Z86cg9L2af1onEe97cRwcT/GDOIMRWT5Dk2MeMdQDkz6m1U34h4c4/2mt9HnAfxXkP6kUv0QgjCGYWXqe7qYBWLrTPUn3z3pVP@KUOiQAh1Y0gkC0MewGnpEXuMxxP0zhTFCOhlEd64R2XwGSyJd1F0XzGgYp54HX94/NGWSyjTO267r6PEHxSUyNDJyYk9rD5jDsUww4YZhh59zgrTlrzFtL2WdhdhjUwrMHLpo1E85vBsqtH2P8jMfPIH7G42eLQoNiG7MWV8kw6BKrg1yP1jCDlAhmHqS55JaCFzEEGbRvpnIQmHK@FHYJv26Ncgf05j5ox1rAGMATYyC4kVAaz5uNZsv2jLOtVkoZALOLRAhocQDdaBFNz3qhG6lvnVpjx1sKstEIKoxKPt4Y1B363MB5BesYNhAxBqeXiXYrByP/kARXCPwKAwTUwyASVYPdScJMVkNr2xQJjNMQFzTmiDV8ZFqkfflRfhioS5z0nLBRQK0IIAwPqwRoQgwLeg7/PlwgHT53HUgTpJXok1YjtJ8Wb8WBkle6Cpc1VWqkCFaSFKAJZEd1tXa1KkE8NEXjSlSkmpd@@0fR33hv9PvQL1ZjTwzLB4yqEO0qeDQRVAi/uxBVWb0WaVfAQNnSLcOFkWuf66f@aA3FbCnBNIOXg1XwzvCj94lI43eTvH3oBUjRFishK8xrNajivMa7Je8XAUk5wcNsnp9tHjCCn58LEICRWZnN8LPNotlmtRoXHGy2JttZBMkZITnjWXjq2RokW342mD0dBMMLNk8LtFM8OykCPJUPo6AGjUXm6acGboO/RNuOuJXgl7mQOcQFPg@hio181m2tLL0RQToitK4AQEa8BqDHPzVbEa4KPFUKfaGM4qQMZBT3@WzAZQUwGIngKrd/nAiZjObAoPCLKRoHoO@KqYYgqrQojH8Z/hPTQWDwU68HZpZTqsuBmfSVv3@QwBZSNtJBI9qHmsmhQMaZzDPbNxwa1Tli@FX2oQNaXefMYYkVyjaEK1M/q9KxnI4y0vE4C36AkofK43kymD/ghgq7O3Ym@sTJ5Sp80mQS260qn88ZzIHt4HdrIjbQQdfrOYZnxyfQqF1nYJuekWZonvLE8Kcdhv9RBiGqJ/tOxxME/5AUn8YiaM5XqOq22/hJ7HY7gWcOk5XwDDUdQUT2jMcFnP@CK5IfxJMP9HCccDovje4keTtMNOjvZzs2uyeJw7EfiaukuwxkWBf0f4gdggbDPGcxcyRj4ahKdyYJ@ljF0Bk5A9D6pp4sYO4r4A8WsBEhfTwmXNJMxyltJfJZB@oliW5aT/pZP3nvrOwTLaEnw/zaMoAlYqSZe5XGSFl3RXHttcXxbEF5R@@P71EU36Ob8aVZ@FWc@dS8xiPfr@hsYgEBEi7QyN6OBlYd5FbvGjpLqITBqFfxDO@MYo@Oi/UQ011Iuusnl/vAH@nQ54EvRPyzdfS/uQGD7Pvv2nw6dHt2NAd5M8Ljkwn61JgX7IwmIPlBEmXP9eJC1r7/jmVBWvzK4wNUIUCNJcFlo51j6JhjmHZ74XJxAPgWnscTWtf4no5t1XjkCpzc0zQ70dY30f12z7D0udFL@CnTEbhBjZ/ChI3k1btVHAUdCT2Hz/USMHYlw1gYxpHoPFFlDcvo6dNkcj1b8SRmyD20Uk4YHqynH8ZfE824xFfjq9UwD4jHY7gce2ri8ud4Pp5zU/oW/86UL0f5@MNbEo043E4QoAMfPdX0otjkTeLzaSKs0juMCGFaebnKaOk6gIiGkK634fuR6PaaQuNGMtWCVhaWPyKzusXNm1o8whUBT/JdpndjyduY7p15LsJqHNhChO293xByDTIe5uh2E1GIPOTGFnPsazIBw2idzl4zqrRXCNQwJ0m6iUnTbdIvkgLOjA/giQtOn8ETAQ6MSZszVFA3XNPyP93IKGakjyNaix8CSjpAiVCRk9xHI5JKCNyQ/PwyLLO7tszutTK7S2WGPWC5yEgiobtUpN8K2Dw3NYFl9CdrpDNG4dwZHjeJbbhsR3dxteI8bsYrZprFT@MVEMhxI17ZT4BQjvfilfvk8OKVI3KcxCufgGPRt@IX8UrQLTCBC15y3MVwX4Sjvxuv7CWSl8JEPzG8oFw5XgnbFNLscC9RBEiB9QatEbfYbMev5sQ1YGAjpTLNkGO8NE6faB0mTb8M/PPPQtEHYzAS1zi3KDFLMXVp0IiMGLwcGDaCDxKs6MkVfzTfP3xAh6HCJFhMCuZ40TwEHtTwWHxZGHHEMJZ2NOAJCKLcrKzGiEVGsndExy8dOJQaebl8op5M@kAvQfENSNxaFELfAvPzB@21DII34LvhiZnX4XkNnaA4wgj3ZJMr0EKivojfUCls62Vc/NaPthCtdS8nAmylIAlvJQIbkemgw9HmHBY2dsbLTEKxeOjejOahRTneKZF7r2QjqeD3zDXRFOzXDAVDtPMnb6pOJB@itiSCMLKRafFeFo4LJIsxaiHrIpoq73yAQkTmQA83uif0nbX7vpPScXGTprFi3TAU5OVFkuRaFpOQWUajVFN9wksPJ6/7aKrq/aavQc4ZrrUkEEAkZ1gKl6/Oe@jvDtffA4U6IMKVAlYp1quH0uvq9Y2j7BXMrUWx1xsQI9PsfnKlchSWsCA5zA4imvlNvHZNxccjH1zJ54WG0K9o@wHZwjnBLXS7OrfgsFBLcE@XA0@0/7e7b91qI1nS/U09RVrCjcqUShI2GCNEW4CwtTcGDxe7fQCrC6kE6tatVeKitt1rZn6cFzjzfx7hvMq8w/w6T7FPfBGZVVlCYHf3PmfPml6rTakqMzIyMjIyMjMu9PLnpfsJdVcj6V77Rmnx0ZKGIx2PMU269jCu0vFZQ4wvfL4ddH/3AI/SA2wPHuBxB0ZTJJdZPrrqs5VLMrdJbMsbiNTSmhJBztel8TAnL0nc89VtfG1LL/YbB9v7e7sfaNF9/vy5q9foSYIfZi3OWuN1XCCzZXW8HszYtix5SIaEy24cx0eXg9H40Wk/c0eWiLAmZSCgVgz76TnuallmyfOpuUv1pKxFUQ3r52QaBCmpBFUnwJLd0XQdE0HCce5JoIEY9Zbo7fFuzeW0P41GP@iFjQYvXybtrF7FMDTmRtz9W/ZR4SoacepnyVl14zgcHUJt76v3r6tH6uh1Te0cb/1Vfdg/Vu@re0cIDPD2eHO3vqXo/9reYU05KTtK5PfDhpLouh02QyRtVUvF4jPFkLcGw4nIndyWK@8Pg556PWiGuKZaj4Ley0v54ffD8YbUqtF2dIIzzA7nc@x1xrC34ASEtI2FctNiR0G4Aigqe0572h72vL1Bq9PuUFkHe99hJ4yMb5nqdmgESd4aF2lPlCTkGmTTIc4hCgusG6oeUHnc3RCYQOyvQGKUkOSELV9pwsX//W4KHtUO3hwqxJjY2t/brh/V9/cO1c7@Af18@6G@94roWT88OqhvHuMTF3yzv13fqW9V@YUgUPQVgj/8dBWNH0TBR3GmSvNn3Hz7Qxr@@Ff61BsavLoJ2GUyUgtXfUifTtDt/Bq2FsrOVQT1BW6afFWgcvPVg1fvaM1X4S@44TRXwWx/kDmOOP/lfFGtc2s0WTZovpX1dKVlL19y@T6iN1FIgROWOShEjp89ZYCzEU@rE6rMFmxUcPYtsSN4LhvQ1NAjgg1QxmClojh11cKCt84gN6i1ZneAQJ/SmhgR6h@o@tKYmpQdppi2lQFQODvU@zgPKpXjF8T39GJJNzseSQH1NH4hBdQzeQFVtA7bEbWsS1yN968gntWKvPipN9zha2H1PH6xGfAudlXjJOPGQxqoOPUfIml0OUGZnPJwElXOSc1VIi6P5F3drkyMUNJGkkyUq0S2baOSGRI2bVw1aLM3ycaMr8QNsBMK2uNI5Squr45gHBT2O5Ia7qIb9MUEKjHdYd5TqwhaVNnQ6kOcUo3dR4YDZkCkc0zjEdfb1lph@K31qObmnRYDbSPJaU2NCdrXENi8g8AfAUOA8qmdTpNXKvZiBZhBW7NyLhoQR@Lc9je7PLFz66oZpipoq63cT51ff3U1kb3UPsnYKTJ2NES/hiNSK/kqsz0Y0RxnscpJqCAFm5eD4bgjY5hL94BvnHiZo9JY2Ki1Hw1xdWugw3SL/UHfavScuPieVs@JKb@lVeZ4uTuPxVeSnZg4nxZhsbsDOsH54Dq07s48XCLdhDh@IUWY78px@DkZMyaifzqJ7PhNIanpamVje/M0/9uPHjKbiliQxMLG6BD/E2OiLZoefM/HBosj6F16ppmMdNHVOWprGzwtLTHLDTDaB152aF/3slGOv4m58d33cLCZfs8vP3@uSK08JJPORh1d5hLp5qkT06THdc6UNgGxZCchS7I@Z954DDOW1y/hVINRQBSePuQI9u1T@d60CDG9O79qk2TRaXf1cMfwXbXBFhVJznI4y9jjUfiY26wsbriFxKBEWeTMGRHtGcgl17XMUni9ugNu@2FwJL@/Hdzqg9jJ8vC7oG0/CO134ZZfvB@WLEsWrG8H@9sDYGVx@0Ngqe/e/YBlkbwLLeb0mDm9@WxsTftwiz/eGTueewQGay9OUGKgVmtXfb6iNmGzc1LBtcEkCtHh0Xbt4EBlZH9CdUnuYcvQ0mIQsB@pt4m1bafPws6PlaZ4sxwrT@ZNyqItdl96YDLPJN49okLrIJ6mRywskuDc7c6tSD29srAKwdb3LBAN5dLYfTIyKDrRgL/QHpCQTQbN6qAzs5tZWXw6kW0ErunmiW5s2/CzhbWs3UhmO5rYgGyboOACniWzx@@96Mdrph1RsBC3CB1ukSZN6w3tEw6p4SEV9P30CD4wLGZIYWQvCnbW0A6GX8W0hv3nGYoZSZRw0YUtsa6VY42a6MfzRs1hg0QsAwEsPfVHsWimD0bE85t1e0DdZNHLpZcgUjKR3vSlzRVU/eyLXsKYGvE6WYkVcnuuzTM2JwbLM5zOatjl@ws9hi30yrR4mG6KpO2DTeX/Pk3JKpFqydB8ZmfMR4K8srz89Guwp3thquf/LGxZQ6bl57g3pP19AjKaRHy8T5xb3/PM94QBHiCdmNabCTNVkVSdGWtKqu@8GNn4ES5yLkTIINY8MsZOt@qq2yncZkOXFcmGzkXu9MGawnFHZdbcof6Xh5uDQP5qe49@f3sy2VAIpoNfYJX/ZjCKwsQrz4rvYr2Cc3z6XTga9bmY@DP1ACXHbkwPOtuxt50YvEqv8JHv2@yetLV3kpjdeuasgRvh40UfSaJxuleePt7Ll8p2V3fquzX1hGNPtlNnkZlRxrVkz6NO/yEEWAbzuQSWD/bhexyt0f@Eg2dAEpnYmy/HtHG/ihtThLTmE848pM1CtWwtTY9@O2oGfUQE8TKPI5XxvqOKfApb299xZ52sF8up@oRcNOznqJaXyfsZrkrvcKALSGkQMpp4by1Y8NQwlpJwr7kYwD4KF1vhrZyeseVkUCitFldeONy7vjf2eicvzrwnzUpG0eIb9HvR1eim9fPF4PK6rbpq@NP5bXPy6y9KLT9TT6mtpe8kAHBppVLgmKvP6d9V9aLInKsR/J6DGSNpsS/ZXJVaUMk@vPxIufzAm@Y1eEhMcal60jNcCBe7caV3snJW6VeK5d5J/6wMJ7/xYmW8WFrM4cV3tIqSjJGb@ZPxGdZU@9Q17F8rhNnkrKHaNUSxawi9eROMOoPd6t6r1GkcFAAcgWlbbz5QlwTRc7Bmg@@J3w9vcvqYzFPgWAcKkjPHXkElOL/zeTKOY1odwoxGxSNtNrrlfyeuM1f0r4bjAX8xERXBWupz57MzZ9yYinyiQEVOOibuIvwLCE5SJoeLIXk7ESvqfEnUtRJ8J10LxAlqsjjMnGYy8CkEotqX6@TMifwwaF4CCWRE/8zV1Po650cnVot8PsWDKUcwYoeJ4hkecQFCf4Z824AmWHOP2O3Doe7jdwkP8obPqMbsJ8MG8g5rivgC82/1if2buP46EUAIPyc6l6@POLXmRYqk@A7y4QJCnaU3/rhmgFulDMocOgvY0l4lAc6W4kwjNKvJRO/nbkBOoRX9p3uQL/GvO92Iy7tSnEnC99T6VwRa8pDypw386SbVcla1vKlmClukmPsqNXDSRdujNyFNq4naCrtdQlpoMZeQA4/s36vbX4zbj07Q5lmMvHzP3/meT3335bsglZTyaYFPCq3ZhTLZT0m5LyqTFPPutFVRrLz4NNJNn1SSpGz5obKRPx40OknhjXgohSvjD@upD3nry8cZoy9fHqXqxAwefz@R75q/l/TIx1imyr5Mt4@/jh6gkI1nta3JFJf6/U73e0cn09ZfwGYZoqZSUp3TJSozqSraB1OLE9LgcM7P03ajkkBZLBmJw3Mms7H@MuNrJeP73DQa4sV4Z2LNmCMWlbjNRSbcLTssUjv8@ZEFgmGC0ZSZuRum8kRXnlhgUeqRaVa8IO9McOra9BSvwC/yM/4xkz2NnCmXnf1xTjC/lc6Ld3OaQCx0H2VmkyktTeAuIi91px5YRZK2J9MQZwuJPesUOG4zFB/sNo7BH8VywhYURlLcoXv8RVM6KVAy7HvfEOLjF@dvhSfOq4B07GE3vFVVbDMC9sJyUg7u4zAaRwgMxUFroqvhsItbR1b4btiFWocVWVrGdUsC0VrZfacOyx4p7@FJO6RTJV/tA/INDESSD9HVxQWcyeABO7iBaMWJS2fsO9X@RA40aM48XRI381Ah@AYL4G7nwkZCRk5mDygdDYNm6Duko0Wk/TjS1XZHpxnl83T4jSD0GC1pa47zT1ed5s9br3Cf@7xUfFqySHatr4OL/tNniYMVEcl8WEL0wOXSM8ex7oabcjecB0BP7WKhf0e8GV6H/X7oVGnF4IIRKa1ROLoOW77jHITxJTDggpVxMwk/7MHVqCmHO6R0BcSM8BKOPLkOIw7DX6zPcl3c5Lsyz8GlVXLbTEN93WmBgMbjpD3A7TBfWCBMgNADlXrhmIjyxFVplPjuWePCuksPB1FEDcQ5se4mYjL0B@NOk0aGT7KcLoGSa5CksX5rChNqr9kN4Bzsz0IA7jEJBQwC5irpIRwcfWn@u3BQumPmjj0wI1Mg6TfguULTPRx1SPomBOZR4WoW7jTAR6/rh@pwf@foffWgpuj57cH@u/p2bVttfuA7blyUcxxe9Xp/l6RLfJsut@b79CJTPaSaGf7gVPc@qNoPbw9qh4dq/0DV37zdrRM0An9Q3Tuq1w49Vd/b2j3e5tt3gqD29o/Ubv1N/YiKHe173Kqp5iT11P6OelM72HpNP6ub9d360Qducad@tIfGcKtfVW@rB0f1rePd6oF6e3zwdv@wptAxZ7t@uLVbrb@pbfvUPrWpau9qe0fq8HV1d3eqo/vv92oHio0ErF5u1gjL6iZtYdES93O7flDbOkKHkqctIh4huOupw7e1rToeaj/UqDvVgw@eBnpY@6djKkQf1Xb1TfUVdc7JfYUqNC5bxwc1REsCJQ6PNw@P6kfHRzX1an9/m2l9WDt4V9@qHZaVs7t/yAQ7Pqx5CnkRuWmCQdSi7/S8eXxYZ7rV945ozTh@C3sHlwb5PRGGsKxS1W0mMMwg0Fsi0v7BB0AFHXgAPPX@dY3eH4CmTK0qqACLiq0juxg1SEQ8srup9mqvduuvantbNXzeB5j39cOaSwNWP0SBOgwyPhDrUKPH3GuME@Elj8SsjuFcj4dT1XdUdftdHZjr0sQBh3XNLUy2rdea5j7i9FqHKJ0BzgyCnn2w0r776jpEZMq7JzKzz2jiiElb@9s1WpF1aKtM8uGYVp3VqVBK9jdaaeKP9DMVsqYVnl9dNDr99gA@pnE1OfjoRRcesv24SJVy6jyQ9Eqfr3CFbLbReFdt0Eb3sNFwvW@pmULjazX0MfhDpVzdR@RRwM4bBz9ra0L39RShNr7TF51sqIcLCJQU6n8npm9BL3RVodAKdTU47wOwOTqK5NrkElcpJBrZ2RE5XpIm@WSCf3c0O3DFnAHvNxs4J4VlJBcaRPRP/3PyQxYH6wVJZznuKhSwiWU0Or@GphlphEMi8D86IkGnzU36URj@fJEr2s1hz@9fDAatnOuaOlx2TPvAi5z7lern4cVU9fx0fUaWr511CoLI7LtZhYnvnzXJlB4Xf8Q9y@Gfxpj/uAYbifmAU1Nuig@r9aFl7jupDoskT@nQFnCv4EGGzvem@kP9PXZzxaVn5an3r@P3MrdgL4gYtrTgnXC9M/7z@kwK0ATjWBxEko6OkFEoWHWMvUlc@IYKXqLQTacFyx9aqy9DXteJJKTIXgVdu02sxqPOrY09yeFXB9U3m8c7OyQ6ge2z1eXnK2UnDrv1gyd/P6AdDjPLUceGtI6TnsafrFmyRYoPzxQrynfC/szAhQIKIn67GTR@iTgPsd1G2pIJggzdjZDwqA8TvUwIOmQUB@B45Bh@nTkzNQPkUl110ZtecMsqfkC6EvOANmbpTnjUbvEPYMfT30zxuEOagTSLceBd4lzaXbDcy@wYU1He3HDgHhTxM4aPJYxbTAM@6mL7WXjX8i/N29YoRmLKiPnKw841CYlH01goY1fRl5n9luOM6ANgjh5Gb37Q/EaPH3SAOw53F0Tj6viQyLgT18Q5dXIYrTt9oiGfIZcGgqqZltYVTvldjRTPPX2cHAcGsWYDo4IEL7DxTQMux3FEpptkC9iXC676JJyK4B2AU9Ycq38T587qjoZSNvFD9G8TlUIJrDjIiVDtJm7DMUU@xHEsDDlTZPpT9GD4/0CazIC/TjtOgp5QywoC@E2UZKhCK9q@MlE6N@aiwbrdSKhpv/qQgPliD8xl3DF9e3Mr/jVEAj06E/PiA4c9bOdmEABMjoMNe/7GJmmXAW2dXmZcXR33JP1mb5hTeq0wS8UduPmVM4/VLs/creCHq1w5a7Ia3KWq6qVs3M551tOWaWorrx5HGQHnmvgfhSd8ABJPeObSS7Faneasop5lRg7oUEvWgtOKIyaRWvrl3lu7J8oKkZmS/frmyxCKQG8An7v95MQiAyXmuemIi7wSqyOOgodg4tgmY/HRIevO2RCzGwLO4xYfhiD3yPgGC0RXoHOovgSayj1mQxE0klgdJnEGIW5dn0jLy@pNjD2fTIJDY@yP@xLHPpRTLVPClwAfGkPbXd5Xb4IJodz9tm4LixWeHA482C6iMTmW0PWRZ6U5GIxIdQzQb8LR60xcX73Xhw5hP7oa6fiFtJ51RvpEwij91AzUJtm98zIjAeQZtagzhrdCy2f@4C71QliISniS2/yKyhHzGh7dMIeOndvFksqtJ1/WiSYclpSJuK5W1OfPUkoIqkOGhkzBThRvLthmk9vBvUM8/W4Go5@x9kMF6rfCVhyZ1ALJZ4EySPU@x3hsjqXrw0HEJxo0FDgBiSlRkoO02FCV1ujnmp20XVMmiY6J2KXck9/fTsykxlqKGkoYV7dOzLeSp8EElZZ0aNA4WGhpaZlRmbXh@nLvZoyjhaavrVXmtB@LlDVRIiqPjeqIJ5Gb8dMHPOlD/srjCLOH3uCOW6ugQBg6K@5V78o5xg82Be874ahln4mSJtMKhjh@463PoM@8aI4Oddi/ZjCOwgntAJqFzm2BYTRyfxlc9htbg25w0Rl0AtqnIQb8rUg8PE74EQN2MRrcRJxCiD@0rEKtSfIs8WUkDBt@x/eSZSs0VzQOhznbTGE8mlQvJUwEn5zDCDDJQsr8PZyOkRbXebacVHLS/qdsj1dyy/fWfVqaVVlu9AFAC7iNKQsK8SEds2OS5XxavlPg/KECFo7nKq8C9x6LvRTGL4hEfA2Twtggc8cswe4Edmb3YnzSuvVaHINwhEBL4XaIdDhRjl97ARI7kxT5HpYCa6q0WrSqyi3KLeIQ4mFyP7mXnv@DsScE/gT6paezuGUWI7CIa5toS5HsV3SUUcKFzQM7LKNZEpMU61x0@pb7IWeguJ2Gmv48uY8abPlDSpEOs3eHKzEjc7TxQaa7XINETmPiYlFZUAsux@2AClId54r3M2z4NftZnvy4xJWTMwimLQ05ZyF9H6maRCWkzp0yr7VRlpjKX58xS0vfOmpTBKzMMjmzUjjnMkZzYQ@UjqyvuNYajEgYZ6aop009FqLxYLjwjdS7V3bMjMw2i9ZN1/2qIbAwW4UWyyctJm1lgsdJ2ZnGZ4pp0hRjSzPiIWxf@Tlm82ki3lYamG@VxuQrdLiPZondVLyoxOPdkrmPRfEaFr1moYmnFOOOIKXl@P1JgzreuF@CaJiyvWqwxGhAZDQm8miBmiJTTKVvpxBzn8Z9ih4tohzabRHt7PG5l6jTRnIm5Kn5lApyCXoicDucNkkuDdswvkCYONFwYyEVK5y33oSv8kr5cwQZxgcBCK04zCfnUHKCmwzWFB9xdoB2rgFroRIkET1t2BYOcdD/mGAclV8f7miLh8YkXzorC6TbGBLtKrjUQ5CMvzn9PGncMpQ7pKApPoMUcY/uyKbLb@/Vn@0LlSMIUps/a0vfoofOuGqRsKF/7E@NW@jASVO6ZmpGpSdCg0UDzQXapVx0Q9muQvvrjITjYd2gpxFtIOR1Dn8WdQ2E814pxtRGldvWBEVcTW6Zba7Kb0iVhKHkN8ivp6KourxxJQChYEz1KyWCgLCmjD0uBTj0js15KUT1GFHFSgnTkl5yVNTEznPGdxBVF3i2bJUozirxwoaRnwmEFIvZZRJESGeZXSSBQgvdTFysEs9n9ycpQQqx4X2hOA2FHpU0DeOREwJywuiim0iUk5LyipqD@eOzZTf1MeZv/vqiaH0tTn8l@sQYnuRL019Xi6mvqWaXltJVUzWJHq7dauojkcK1EY6lwp/7j11T7JDnsU2otclIaRnaPhsJvWmXSfs2/6dIrbNTttExDDzbM9xsvxqSYiUVlP3hAOxqga8MELv9T/fWWKYaTHSuAI5LZ5xdcrIhZI01g6Ue3cJO10TaiwMUmD3toK3eHe3spMK@nk@MoVEvHC0Xi0Uw8bkd/N7YVuMoqTMopEsX2lfdbmF485fRu/MCy/4w5JQAa2YHHdKQ0KSI/MHoQjJDAAcqitJ57ciKvf5Vu22nYMANJQaPhk1K6mgIihegTmz08u6ID4AYpF5gf0QH0b8fVTz7bgJRNDUUcw1FtWESfJ0xt2dEHrxowz47vqliYBDMxpqJ1i23svEJKwgym/Bgcfhi91Ninpx5HXa7A0@9RxJiRAqY@zJdYWfHrlCUIrhhZO/eq4jj0XoqvO50Lb9iFLF5HeDMwmTyTJi48IiNfxBe1G6HuczJxwwtK9TlRXRzEfGpPZW5yLg6WPw3gBU@JLS/qXQvGOaaTKfpwrTU6xmcPBFGT0vezL1PqojLZ2KaZl8vDaLORtfnYA3UdZd1ARPLnoeXe3JP8Zi4mdPbUhs0LAoMjRNirnxbDbia/ePE4vW43f42qchpAGRgf5dElEwof04g8h0Az0A9/YieiKL91zxN652pgCKi4CBZx125gwoNVHCcx83KLze5arWq5oeLi6pa3aSHfF5VN6tqGy82N9U2/d7E7@8qS8vLZZG52@4nerlpXn5RmwSDTzgXm5ejbfpJ3yrwG4O1NoZ4vlCZ98rzjcr6RjkqnFQ34dZPT//5L//zP//1fxWq@se/48cm/zj5GBfyfb8w3/w0/92XMn6fbJ8tzJ@fzA/PFi7K4LK/cdTwQX2cDxLzUX907mRlFbDesh2p2Wdz9BldVZkUgL1g9DNJlzWVbUaFrH4bSeYolrHZZmi9D@FHeU5beJN0YHorT0hkCegEx/E0Os0QBni03hAlCRfYgUp9uVsxB/cIBxMXiG9VsjoSD@us1yF8WpJICvDFpRUr3@lHYR8n4Nes80r3HCegv51xQ/Nv4eOb6GJzcKuenObUk6J64qknmQz/Ka28oLfufKED71wpRtuBTMajL8nVAswMVdRhRY/3D5xrZ4rcjjPPKXsAyYSp4MLiBefFuz92lpGEa9GFM4c8nEqOSPiSCVWyn@b7X2hYPlGJL5mUqw0rCg29i@HGrBuVeHyhAgWRGAIkLfeEIGsDahI3feyRjKeCeaPH2uFsQgwYZD14tcPzHi9oLZrva5vn1F4KaY7YfF7eYm0sizM0o40v0n6CAF@oyHayyJ6EC9kFR6y8rV5yN8UL2@6fZj6xdZiEY2ObLpV@UxYTiDW3Tbj5vvZr0Ybccr2iMp34esVqKjNt@60cq0rvqjvuDLW7AreOCfUpbu2LzCSMKAMSOBKzf@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@LBYJCBECrmTj4WzzwVC6DSLlPSnWSFIasiASeHh9goAX7iDZjaNRSHrzLlPXDP4ue9LrqK1lf9iDOWFK38JC7Op5GN62ueM2gSK/XR/uRKXk6iwulR8tlR6Rjuhi/A2PwqvsN7mo6vz8JZUiQjbWVp6Tn9NcUOKEF9uo6BML2@pn5LWRHxPIu2kpEWonubcjhOzFdXxhSeoPFGZw6XCxcWNywS4fMSG31PEcqYsx4IS00GL@3JYP6NBD@0EEeTatHeIcCSsDMRGhI9Q84Bskq/cx6GumS4L7Ofkqy3EbmUgNLyFrLVa9Af9vFbWXH@hDCUaXjPd1eJqcXqO3pmiqRk6r5WphUeqtPH98//4t/1fsuPsxlLh/Yj@jrO/ZFdWs/JID/Trqfl1nd3IrqPYypfspEB7YHp8/h//m@pv/IXg4Mtknf7ZWDawVibZjXyFq3zObqzQQ2lpidr9P//8z9SHedmxIRfrfMNTjFjZUGQr6DPv0ndVRy9lW7qQiBV2zAIMsTCkvTn9gGHU7dJqkY/pstqq4jrUka@MPYpe4tkwa8ymQnKSYewpSDOSChU0kBeQxoSirSzbDWO2AeZN0FQ/PvZXItoB/KjNOeImY9ONxxFMhuZlW0QDmJMWaT8vDxvF7zOxecdaxtiUlI0Kia2dlrWrT8vEDm8H4bjTTFtJmOnaawY34bkPPvTD1hXtqfpRd/DTqHBNLNkrLa0W2jjcL7Add2HIkPLDif8rKYI6GRBtDNno1FMjGoFBDyG8PM4WRAr9TnwnZfJJkpY9DJtyhpXOSUxFxMfPk@thdMdPVOkc/0sKPDJn6kSQVq600z7V3D9YU5nFuKCU4z2vC2zesnGsDoGRF2vYIcsm3@E@4HTQ9Mevji7YCYlrIeq6FPGDVqsR6G85Zy5jUqV5ztxl2B1WMm0J747Yqbgx0fQXNfNeKPkOThDyeRZ0gNULxwFt0SsZfoP9eNICwqTou9Y4VFxC1rYuq3f1rQpnXXmg6Rtp@oZGFFpC0k7MM1Y0NmUXE9lSwVHlKGzgSm1mw9RaZJI2j3z@AwwiGZZ6G24JujvsAUlUS7qjrcrsYfN4L0w8chOKz54cLUrmaiebOD96poR4UEN3Qru@NEYCAlFw12ChTL8PxQOiYtKMdvqOxPOb@mzie2gw3Id9hBK1w9ZJ8FFZlvrXyH3TGbMvpSIS6Liytg22I6tHDDoOsRWnoM3g4CXjgqXaa7zZ4oJmONY4DbQJCZXJyDnVSVPF6WXbOnutJIqgF5liaenps@WV56svkOVsTvd2NhhU8rELGF4GBIM16hxtsvG@UsksZOQVUlDfbRLQZ4HFBRzMum5c14R9vnEfVUpFDayYYVg3nEZDquvjSgaZQByFPlYE2qPkRplc7vu1E3Ts7LTlfqb/ib9NfEBmOBOONhDSW@PwNolM5fQk4ECFBTMHxck9RQQVV3@xy4aD9gGiTYSwdRW2p4Z2EQFifDkaXF1c2tzh69BWRzRhiOAclxo7qFfhOAkwZmEFXVQfONQt74uKgXdytwcwysWSAJ1PgNM003ErA21pitmxQIsQImvCYxVXiJbpqM3OzJ39gartbU8jlrXT0DFc37ZsJeWOI5khgAxy9VrdPSLq6mgX7EqqZZKXiqrMAq6IciV2hw/gK91EImqLKkZWs94wzj1ElhLzYhLaNKlK4wi8ZsAsFb9OSuPXanoBghhBqE@TYiHmxfc5NskSnOxBxjwFL2fWLBvRN50o4gBzurGMqy1KuRBnFZhz7gGIc5tiRjpSXMOI8mONEy/LaCOZo3hF42hAmyHHO9VwZklOM8FWt5EEwEbWcUML9L@@t@Wp7Rr9s/N@24OivFn9K/odp3i@H9@Sxre0puo7ZgjsaLFscwubqV/gokTMUtQBYxMEIXzbkhUxTKIG1Oo7mvYyqU9Sc/ss4Qqwa6CVcHM6qicJAr3wGcic3rzHoTjYXYffrcnh1V1JE4dU0dNCjrgentgWTeaSVmNIQspvALE0DSIO1JJw@1zC8GKBzpp3oPcuhrHrO7N5OsWysqEitX2nQGRP8@y9lHmILZY0WyytYRwf4gvm2wd54zxsD7QvWswcX@GNR3@MN/Lfzhz5/xbMUfvHcMdTzR1P1yB7hDvisOHs0clp2AczOOZ8wmtwo9W56OB8qG39RCeKngWABR4whA8pfSwV0bd7xInKzf6wOL0ewUhoaRmOAX@o889055@tQeby43b4X7Xz@b9z55d155fXsNbMGHmt2lnh1v8@PU5Uwlz6xczhhborxdw/2tMV3dOVNaymM4b5/3tP8/@Pevpc9/T5GiImyIWDhK9/mJtFE6kebtXribmF7@igXTnksZ/NlS72Xq1KhjYP7e5VdFmBtq7@MP6rGv9VSCN@Qho63EXEtqHxXl62p@IsL5oln3IoOFlJT6S/JjK61V@9YCX7Eb1AiZDmg62R3qiQQu7Jx@S2yU/0x0T6xovPt@Issl0ny8TFubWBlh1hyU2muGi@Oknm0kq8rmxzDGS1dXSwu/g/hAy94GfthUbIY2hvwm7XrCT2FuwojjqlO2N1B7AP9Z4jxSqanIzsWHt7x@wyd79U48AWU@vi7E2CXLXh/o/2Uj3oG1ZWbhwZEW18Xd/sqmCaa7YX8ob6LoVmd1n3@A9x6QvNpS/W1IHeGNxHqkAf@GleTPZpS8vLD60BUsvHH0zAokflH5hV/xc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/u52gt)

Command line: `java -jar ASlowLanguageInterpreter.jar --nodelay polyglot`. Run it on Linux because `Scanner` silently fails
on Windows because default encoding is not UTF-8, or replace `new Scanner(file)` with `new Scanner(file, "UTF-8")`.

Added a `d` on line 1 to send it down, and then:

```
r3o5o8ox
```

Answer (score 3):

## 359. [Maze v2](https://github.com/olls/maze-interpreter-v2), 16024 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx r3o5o8ox xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcu c 11 xx   .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"ullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrl61op>0#astd[]!!92[]?42>805在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML ma5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NYdiD4saPg@RFXoCpJigRAgG9SpFKpVFaqKrOUnVJWlYtkMkESJJECASZASmRKyuju2e11255ZT097ot32uNo969n2eiLGO7Gzbu/YMxH2fpxwzCf/gPRjY8Ox4f4HveecC4CgREqZ7XHExMZCInBxH@eee@655577Oujo3vBnP4vhxZ441nxgORM2MbwJ67nmqeHK7N6c3dVNL69lBQFj7bqD6ciwJ15FiDGVMUu3B1N9YLC@aU0MN808w2Adw3LOIFxjbHtqTz2jV4e3LGO2ccYO7K7ZAwhs4pwYtvnacCEsx9h9w7oYXUxY1xmNdLvnsbFr2hMKzTP2RIeX/rR7wvSON3H17sR0bAgqMPbMtvRRp6czij52DZ6oyABU94TSLIeUGHvsuJ4BOThdw/Mc9CyDp@6azqPdTz@6El/NsI90QGpsGbMr2asq@9w03N7VFBr77PjBg6u@WfaJ5NjswXWU1BzbnU6cg8lV@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBhaAmBPDKmVKmatBRahPY2J2l/KBgAemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2ZkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGPMzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7QkwB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/n2jMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPhobtMzOAkwHEscOxejkl1IwFz@u9HssAHwMeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPHBeoBrECjHxgxNe8jMYM6gyqqO9UWD6TgfD90Aex1S3P8ZFZRg0DbWirVGcI94nrDFx9BNToGUTTzw6eMK/ruPAGP4zL29NNYLr6hG1vs/j@p/fjrB5Wi@x2hLCKauwcqiAWBLJT3ZoCh0RrwoH6ccPUAlZZfCNeYXEgi5ZhuRzLQbMtMS0PRFIzZXBA@9eyKvwKTCuxnAotKB9PYz59Vx@YlsGhDBBKERlfyzMN7pkcy6olHnPgWH0erUuZFVm2xApFVsyzItzLrKxBbgg6x9RyHn4F@AG0MqCiwi@b44AWfA98iry2x/r6yLTmPnQC32V5lRUBIuCrAmStBBDgmc3iLws/Qmv5isKeDIHaQ/0UwEuWeYLSyAgFElahAg9la0shiYgil2fvDTF7IB0QLV9iRci@AJTIAQpAWa0E2eczvCDe0LAsP9nQw2SEbTEDP8C8CHQoAfUzQMsMErMIP3gHeaeBYNNAimkgmDQQJpoG7ixmAfEKEFaAqiz49Brq3glkxPPRekR8kOgARkVqoxBTkUgAAWqLZaHOCiwHjJBFRshnGeAPuBQLDORYSWWlHCsVGdCznGFQNyrghVyigvxUAR8VgUH9q8AAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjikzUJaII2agzQ5cEPFqQX8QTrgDBWyVCFPTSsvmBBw0/JQ3nyWuFMrQO0WIQzopgGuGrCTBthqJQjHtCWgYQmZtxhPc0LoSAeoFWR34EMgRh7wIbgQF9xaMcvpp1vjod5Bac1TdvqYtIDNoIBkhKQZLB48c0hNQCUDYLAVAPoacEAWyJGFqs3mMPtLARow766j4g@kxOfY9FGYocAGYeWQKF7wZMIOxE0SpOOy5ARRZgFvQnfR1VGsYSM3SEgFcMyJzCAT6FsN5xR1AZI0S9l4JI06Lnb90HX0DNdlGBf0BS9Ncsubdjzj1RQ7pwVefRCEBsjLvm5aIQLUOPUJSVV4xj3Ib76Mdt91RtSCRyiXLMcZr@kDQAqeIaCHzpmxQH0hJPXx2IKuCPwN3hMCMmc6KTGk8URz5QhBIkzXHZoAkLICEW66Rpdo7xcdUmdB2C@jWGFa/U4WodyL9FFZNnZAfnuYxp5aVgU6D6PLsnWlZ5wq6MP7seX@C3EIejbon3wQHR0UEMScsAgh3dFk6jOPg5r1nNFy0bjQOgiLPjSxt7HO9DnUXh/klTHTR6AmMdRFbOghR8AxvAaxJkARxGIdsJ5jxychlDMXNAModFgS0j6QJhNzZIBK6UASrPEcIY0ikzDrzIGViVo5mXRIjskVQsnCVUJxj1zEgzcW6EN70y5SDfM2beIg6Hs8VJxcQ@9xP2HismZTh58LneTYV5tldGDEI0QtonVBD2sA9X11pksQseM3bA90NU9mJiq1wPkDpw/MdmZC2UFdgqQL2F0iApIg9JrJXVkgkiMDjU4sZrLueMzAH5QQYM8HmRL0685Lk72GQGsIell36rpzNhtDTZgjiDXpOv0@cO9rYzwEEGzUY915F5onVDJyj9BzSCJ1x8vFXLxtGhDHRk1v78kvsoEBZActoI8qP7L8ogDjMRWBSKHbXEOwdaAUFqE7nhNZAEyYou84Mvr3HMMjZnHck7DpY2aeMaCmAe2svxBGI9R4gEtt0tR6IHn85oXwMUNhZWEwK58LPjJsaDpd4Epo9FB9WKe7rA8jl4hegMqb3u0a44nPJw6JM9OOKFGHD1CJIl/JByZ7Q2HzLtu@wjUQNeSciIKASiWiPvZ1Ox1lrT88ApXBNhZ6PJcs1vxa9hDj9Eru4guMs4TBC3ENDmNqEqhRkpCYTlCUoHQ0u0OUhROUNqTEQGtzp9eLD37R7N0Rk/ph3oiNCmJHkJXQC/FYD0OCn3UdkDy2EFZ9yQOjLnncAlr3RisgOyGSVi/qKyu6DELxNqAjx3ZWQAVihnAxynII1QUx4xFKDd0KmZGai7dURyiwFyN27MigDx2PHRdaBhc6cxqeUZVFuMsf1STCviIJo/3lrhW6jDh2@BPsBSHB2IKxHDUxbKmgruogKUCI8VEHyDyH5xhBmFo9wfLxOyPRz5kJ@lLbNlDj1d05BwLFg@4ZMpoz03VBDJ5iJ8H7oKAzkYlPoU@A8RdKViQHtfurmcvI0XvTjjm7OrTpoqf80hNOdZf1cVTjgtIBjSgR73vxZJX8KWUkSFSc8UShpPwuQkSKJEOVJ/owUIJO4gEImqO53U2IS01MTDNxOumXxCQ4MCHX0djH@nhyFbuX4IdMMzqBdk1vVTaA7luS4C6hH2GCAYqMAboLegY0QlDdy@VeR2cXID1giD7bo9SoZNJTlXNhXobdC/PyCYG4RMsr8yw8t0sOKdKrYQkwOpWcOoklAr4jJSihCB6K4vet6EHaHg8jvYZ7Tm2a3GAJrook2Xmo7EMHkCBkTFA@zK45afvqyp07geKyUasBs4E2BWKzl4wOE4JZIBkkNUSWSRvxM5EnztEE20YiCeXFyJccG1CbgFNrdXY@GbrQ4uj9UoBIQFbBRk4OCOvX86fmybR3taJt9MRIIrY6UJrM7kSsCtD589ZQu4mq8SWqwlAijlRF5sX0BPoa85IvVqjoR3MND9Xfmo9KpIYTiIHPqytJxJP6fguG3pt3LV8l4C5o7FwadQD9E392IBREaV8nCBrttZbKgWBz4HDYk93jhzW/LfJApWPalSUPy@nqFnlvYnQxSPvo4N7T3ae/2F4BwzI7laseipkrFbCrnc6kgT1VcrJW2YzCWAC@374ZNiZcjiMKfjCTnFlEVZp3oXOZBeQ8fPrJVZKAJoTkoBzAjb8rKg2PA0qX0NG94ZVOmA1SKcgyTBLEZdIBC2CGDkQdw/UAnyfT16@x8q4iNfb9ETNrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8ooAFQZ0@7xEpLWihpo2ztwtXNGaAz0eoNV9FhlTpCMt8dPhg/2mNwPqTFRJFUbwJ6FK625OB561pzxBWxQHxB64uS8kLxFGfJlxXErjbXSLwom7ZGvgAAMc6ssMkaxQUzRsC7ntXy0a@UjfkAHonCFf1yqg@1H1fRCN4YBfXxSHvql6UAhadVei1sscKQ5e7rW4@bxRz5Wi31V3k2YsCpZlW6AcCvdGFoBNPQh95oUX6arWP/tGja4h7pETCUEAKMPMsJlNeniXg6EUyWdxT9mCE5liG/DlJPJGJSUWJB5OtctejwWck/v7MnCQySf5UkxAXct/dPdDuB5H9eUCayaBBA47FsWdy@7ho0vWAR2zHcgYO24I0XDsMMgS1aW0xdweOfa2GdPTEosZw3QXkL07c6GPoa8zXNHCkVNHhKl/B0W3vDKS0WsgikYhCBEqh@PJL/VQHci3KfXTw5T50Imo@kwndGbqABJE0RC50dSO@5MEkyEj28VlZwHAN5lprDwKkyCIIFtoXdGHC3UXwSk@SmLKyMv5KlD52rlH8pTO/wlrgw1kLHBGSHXz65NHBp/uPd79oTrR8fuk9lykXgHCQXwd0IXnI6YatdYs3TSwWgotB23CxeYEUmMIAJZiCn3ouCG4Zo8gcgTVcw1evEh87QzvuJa8W5gxDpZd2l7PQY2x8PKqfEAbaPQsHIy5fAsT@HPlnOJmMvYqiQCsfTjsyDFqVl13H0gcKpYOOwbIUFYcuB4c4r@GtSgHIeHODp@CTW6A6zGkGUbdGDgxeaCERRQNLcPA0a2WZgyGMhXG10XCTcsjBVBqlByMEGCsrYdlIANMb0NZ/BvUkctb@QNVKnK/VjJZTxCDaUvOHuBt9A4ZOCeitgBTJK6@sead5h81BSiOkq0BiTN6iSQ6PYV9gMVAkadYUx/kBcUha4Hwpygqi0aspzuaClFLymVxRLeQVGJbBMA10Vgnn3KSRPukOpYkjATzJ6dO8QYQL@15Xt/vylu8IkAW970MoarbxvNm0W6CgN@8QbriY15i3GmorWWXXk2z58ZNV4N6l4iHvBh7Au@QE1qQnWyPPevp1cdbTqXX1mDIZjf0@Rxqzx7ugSL12QF73jGjbwwRKNFDZWoqrYOQ3yooJIQuTCnhDSinQoKCnBdZTEC8JlF5UD4FzQG5FErDFbAYvB180j8gRHHQj35tO3KOZf9RrcLbUGwMRabK5i1Law/nBCfSOIeejlIbKRSHNzow4zqPrHp@thET@wmmQHsZqIQSalQ9npO1wqRiYgFLR8BwkB/AVTpsOF7OMOOgHToMMCSecfAANwqbVgwHIGUjMC7LLC8JzIp/lIp3YzpmN0DoGK0kdc8In@52piwuIZi9aNoie1XgcgEaFi8h1WmnsGF0@y8oTUylgEKizkTFycCoBtCsSBQYVQeerlDgW9HDGGppVRsJlGIAvsbt7IMW6Bp8vkkY4iAKW2mfxiavsSl8quvQauPkG3QoLH6liv9KPAwIsrxnTLIk/A0raiTOiSJ/TfAsG3gvUXWE8nwyhxMBhol5zxoZ9dczHR4SJZJXWduNxEPimnTiPb2xsxCvxejwNrh1wbaNrB10pcO2QSyIXxpPRRSnS5MLQBqVAv1b8shFAniVbyAMz1Bxem@OE3qhUsq203lD9p4bPJFQFUB5iS/gAOPFkrYbOZFKsn@GaDejvkbLvIe8cdV1z7JPgY1AI@LtPgywRAYb3qM27RhXHpjdTZFRzYdBooIqZcOPNRqbZap43e6nmZTyNqZNVvQbjQxBek8RIHrjOdAyKWyNXkUC2JRvZSqvaqcUz8a1EoiRZkJGeTH5YSqZ0TutE3ACeSjSbcSCpT51Gd@gSvFlaSyZDQgEefRNGGZaViMvnJci/k2wlU3FIm4ynQSzX4nGgSxeJ4FGhcUaAM9EDcwakhIYJXVx0TYEEJC1OYXP90hgP5240QjjrBlo2zqAvNgDgPgmU4lEp@Zqnjyp0SyP9QO/l8UC5xck71JfGcy7dBY5pU1nabhL0u6dSf@RMdOUzGQZNcqS7jG/EFUmCnpBCOCQq9mPTwyas24Yz9aIzjSsnQDF38D0eTkFYBnt@0sBV5lgwukOHxTfvAnQWrvdgV4JLVxJfAAsA9Loy/FCIolaCiyWgXdAuDRPkIu1voVkZlZDgoieYm88Xxq/kMLcqpWEZzMgc2I5rSEASSCHQlhTa6CTUmb8r5oBmvq6tS/ih1KXhwNs0QCI@sBydaMvFdWQ9aDyKpIfxOSR5avQEC@RHH8SjzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hB4CSoOSWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEtjhRgP56A6UzjPW0zSt0M33K0EYcgUQewiVhKNSG4a4QZCkQmDSr@R9Pi0UjNE/Pby/z@dOqLPF7hXn0dojpzcFvdIfNz017EGa7QM/mbYzMoEMQfrXJ9ZTx5nwUT68rJuZ4YNmczS1dJrzuTotc2O6rtNxLJoKuinpIv7U9XRL55NQQejuZ49B1392fFSTK5FIin46ujFvnIdcnS2n50F0zZHWW4PlIY8zpriZF7HfCrbSoZjxAwoYMPU30kEdBf5F9A@aFK6h@P4l9B/hJjrQlf1ZBHoNPf2IZYqIG@twF5Hvea5mLtF/7RgsjKdSPK44LrA9VzXyP530@0veWfI@kVA0WQvvHHnzDXZLY8QoSnkeCXfbLcWJAipQnHDT3dp4RYo3ph14criy@DjchDA0rGBp8SloLLh8Bp2@hXoVDFpQRecb4wzQsMe4SkKiG9feWBeUUO/afAY0trHEYwuxDWpA0LkpqNIImwrz576r1IRsx1@z9LhYdWDMT9Mq23W@yo1jKpcP5xQ@K7/ZBhDb9Wqwi2ldNMwpHg@jEVTCDVJQMWlh/1pRw20aHk22C5SkKngKDCdmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrQvYFyCW9A27ygDo4oZrqNXNQiJ@zpsZ84k0PgwFp@47g5BzrDUbJmUUD9Tu@9YPYmvkgHDMD6@wgryNymEW@P8HZCG6Qa74mhbIk@K8jWyoe4a3CtVWr8eIbIFLwQEzeecXZykTy9YA7q8U9kbW@akxS7lidMeIkkmU9e@ulmP66Cuq889wd/jUmO7Tz/6rJFpcQjCSMeVrxKvxVmw5xMUZ1CUcHMuuHCnzsSckCZAOxFMLK8qA1IzWiQB9AEGz6DKwoz8EiHqF8bFoix9A0aqCQMx9@ajNDOSl3Lf0icTw@Y8x5cf15ObrxP52dQo@x1/0aHCMrQyA5qpiWGAYpUdHd/ff/pUBs71EvF9XMGpQHPUu0NQUNYVOqBktPAV9mEvzj7ENEkctgvQ1GD00fbTA1NXgelh/AG5o@wYGG4CPJO4@NIFb1rvooRcQ/MJhPutuhOiUQgsYSShTASsshL/ZzYfavl4VoDjU0RJIHfiTgVoayblqW2@kj3oaEhvhShxPliF/qK2mSAptqkmiXtcc4RLxzDCIqURStBoMOk1SDmILLJWq8r3AEBcHIC5A6SuKFJV0NbgmhpUfQ28QaUhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM39XLyx@BixCWQXvGymw3E9TerzVkjgNfC@SS@xkNp69saa@wTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TJHQof1Vy/uklndhQSNDUUJTMViQQCTE/D3XPs9SOEl@GPNgMvJIJNl5SHQNSc4uLoiGbFNjRENwqYxXxmUw@gTB9MiB0jzy91tHtQNqrf5GEmyzTUEMhlnLK7UYwlV45fSKdiqditF0XDs07ROH1ntCVzsjq3nUCMPUoxPresq@6Q3pthQ1xIHH1dZh5406fbqtiEDLHv6COnnQhLqvC4MSqStP6UFz6ytyXt5EspRtx@hP7QGtPqKbSa9uiSmVSxS53@mY66ICEXBfWPBcEQ2EFPKzJudkNdjAjVMx0B@B4OKjl0XRr@4/Ykt0h95hAqn853/@Rg/of712htBR4Mxj6GhD1401JfXXVpafFF/otrpi@QT51DJ1Igy5bgPZ1V0okm6FjtWgaRFekqD7H@GSgl/jwJt4A63xBjbjmPMVweC5OpNVi2o2iMzuurhX9mPxrGj5BwZ2PSICV4JMgxKR6OKVYMz4EkxkiI1i7Hakgk1TjJiZ1/twOpnyOyiut1aiOcbfTW3Tj5nJ6x3VgKGj3jGNG6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPbWwIu6i9LQGLIE64C8Ht9G5uvi8gK45gH42eK6LtujalDN63MYVnj31xlKHRuE9/kYNYXRDDq7F7@uimP6JqNCxnmqmRbd35EQfOjCKvxtCwb2mUoRo5hUyW3pnjjrI8P25LNxZABKn1k2lMtk1S8vj8fr0OJKk9OXy6tQzucvpsWqOQOH7WSU@i0YF9ne43lKr0F2ZI92StF7EuVaYr9qYcC1quKZJaYxTXNE5XVlzC@pjh9SdWrq7cN3A4gs8gmWEdTPSfrfxxOw6oA6MmVqUVS3oOiIdBonMYGvcIiPcTky3yPYHcxUZezAsxE5cCl2rRYDTneCW0TU89Q4CjW/VxA2xESaRnXWU6jpn@FurPgxhaMrvq3u01yuxegfhJFldS4d@fG13sDQ5iJOPtzDqmekZdFtN2JOViE661kr/5SYQTPtFp/FuY2vPtByPHdH9JgINXKACv69m6CgtTd2WaDI86r5BBgV7HBYVqlsDxyqUBooOt7W1PnX7KPf957tKuFBCqeotEipQfxxb9Z9r5fqJ4p7cVkF0CszF/a0R5w1d7Cox5a@9rC8dDAxw4W51yR5kSpRSVvhU35qMccnlTJ8Hz5@j61hH2qDrGM9JnQbtDhOUS@CYuFzF/nlyy92cW@/dhNI1sMXbChGp3BPLgM6K7teqlGkZ9T1TqJnMu4uovjU1psbKgcZh56WBZ5VvGGS8O1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1mt/ZPhOWGM/jW83ChPdMrvG7arMslAbg/Y9xqHzE3A8Qcf1FAN7Ol6q1aXRmf30ZpINx0GTdnpL2GHI@8qh0i2a0pJ@7hn0u3HExEd4uEGslstkMr4CE1lxWXq5aSSVDdO@NPl9KWPyWeS8iIurbG7EuToPIkt0C@JaEaStG9hT5HJZsU3bmMzx/o7StOM41vvUFAjVnomqGGiWtNX2phq7pu74h0jYYurCwwmPTn/dpAXvbfyxJdAHB803VXp0SeidalPCRc8RLkgtv948fRNZYLotFzzMjXNCfPOttV6X9GdDVLkkF29sdVxDdTqGpfPHrJC7CV5Zzt4Ib1lo@Iu1uLjLl3QXS/GxK0JpPAdimT0YpQyNkUGvN2j5eg/tDviPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vM9o3uughjE@SCjfelNeSIsjRxbBhfTXCfH45TLNxJ6vuuk8DBqt9KIh@M9IHBDWHcJCkXExa4m4YP6xbO1VMXFb6DpgvJFhYO1rMENKoTY@4Fz5UAH8@7UK/T0e3TbVcafxfnQN@hta/bwnq9i7WHztAeGkO@bzx8W9c4gB8n3HDJTagD1oMhbmUbj5e2uEfpaTmW9S70RNHIBaXj9FfitI@HX/Hk1nvBnesdCPAft07e6RMuO9CxttUMjSn0S54zccaGRG/rolo40cPv62RosEj9884g3TjOB4oEz58X/q1jy4HuTMZjerTH1tSjGyWV6MzybXpTn29NoU2RjjuQXzujjux7yv6@FVoCXy1iOuakO8RD45yzjYHT6Q7N25DuGPrENk@UYMqHv77T2BUpYzLpPnrLlgnkdecy8kstGn6Ej4N1le7PHvFuLXTcoK@smqGjY9nSWD/penw2FF2sghPCkdbID29X6Ph75dXUnCyARvYyhdO7fFkCHetw93dPrNWs6IzEQgz7uyrWcikp6aiQS0YGFB51XbbL@9wiTSyb5bd1CEVLSRhF9qW8D7n9vT80O2hG5m3Bf4m/ljYtrezk7OF04F0XmHy6vgcqGt7WT1vQXubIlDX0WbrtP9aRWbMUPOQIzzboXFPjxjWV/I2LKhRPtSTdMeHRhgdU3XTtHJpljj1@Z1J/7VKcv5cJxuJX1ws5bearB9N@xfSMPl8CQddtKuLIcXEnMuggUhdX0nEGHYU5V7y44LKdAQh1yWKLyEHcdWrLym1Cq6s/7DOlLz41BjrutX5kTnCz5gquIJZdtb3oVthfn@qe@fUplGwds6HFBr4M6UaP9uPbCniP9YHZfbhUESGSPoH9nZ78scT@6HW9Ls6Gpoc7mkLHDRNTyHKciZHr2jBuWBHz6rx9aKxi0YD4MciVsVfNrTvjOZ4Wm5Prpml1c0KzrP5z3dBx3SawG5E4m47GU89/rMaB9kxFZ6FHJ@TvnZkAXHoFopUNdWuyeqY6MuUKWpjfKS6c67TxL03LGbAvSxkGShsoYaicr2Cce9A9P8ENOa69ghMp73dc9sSJDsnlBXsFdWtkmWTa5uTm2ZzJBDfnBE8sDO858ISC8gjv8t33hSAdr6bIo9t1/cXR5Fv6d@C8I2fqdg10hvZGosMCP1djL9h9jCc6HLSXchYdpXUdC5oXOKyVTabr2NOJ5E7tG3uFwo29QoXNSoUIG7DE1/cfP0tGuYF2a9@mhRow@Jt61nzhWrth4AqTmTYoYuvl6HLsYCxxn9tJekpbhW9Js4vGnLokru87q8Y7T@bQgbzzgAmE/3R03@jisuGteX/qPHZsB3qjMQjK0VODn/lf2uixOiEme4Sn2oE@vVuzOSKwazohrm3oY6MD9WstXO/SF3HA9/WJvqYrorlBGv@Frlt5xbQ6hvuSJv0i7nVD2mWEHhozGlusZxjeBqVJt8tVYpyPW2ojSys23thxbH4naZuBh/r4ZqkCXQHd3n2hXMaN@EvzAivHZ8tFPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6srtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxyTQvrwbZUjxRhmyGBqBJnuqe7RIv3qosQCpzt5jC9BQd7sOroT5jht250QME9wipsO9/XzjQAcIPwOJpXenvgXG29CyRp0R3dYOGCK1@dTo4KmgDlnzmOiz65XJZ4Z8UwaRHV2hAYBAXGGjLrDEExiNJG/vtpbGUctUNcd0I0m9drmcNutItml0X@s4a@YQvRZz00vhUGblU3KumauONCOaRVZ0Oum@siUtb10DhcYypMnQhTG/Mrlpejsws7JiPWQ6MnCReXkVZq3q6nhDKqyzej09FK6uIfm2/kCWhHb/uH4o7a7VPBE8/B/e@1iBTrhdyAWmR0B03b6CD8hPXdt/vAsHPnG8Sd@cHQLeeApgnTjBYuUhCTx4y0DX1rpCQO3ZU4vPPgwi@65GPRqOSWTaVpIsEtcTQzLsU4kMwc2ul8jhh76UXTSJOjF6km8HAVcapEfB@a8wmv9csYAalY242VNVOGFnhZy//XMVcc8CyQD6ljORxh49lbH35ODR4bE89tSV/dPuEE9HXNPjlgwraKVMZErqpe5G1jv5drSe6U2Ue0eqtPfoQMYIa@jNVzQkeODK3NJj7bynb29UV/S1oyAMNSarFcSHx48fpRZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47OkrjSZOPj1YGR1M/gNbRd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfs@s2l1cJ30XJHTOkjHBoxGgRkfcrsstypXXWds9I7nY@Mz6DxRgnvvmH1hbSE/1U/NAbZCVl5LKGqorCwXcsnIzmwYbBtu@FxXnyfmGKVllx4Kf6zdjoKaQ1Zxs6u1h5tW/K9qMSzj70R4v0Rq5jq3TkwJWsZgiC5F9/6@iKmquo7OR3of6pXl11bWcoRV68OWc/oOS8mGP3iRQi9pAlwlmbfuIy9KIxDdCt5wet73BGdn7TaYmwCE3oWVDf7MsOe6LdFa1k3qRQVS46a2G6N8abzDglS4w@cULUCvXOMLt9SzRJecyVsyPnYjSfb27h3cluCpT8ubY3306TP2RPfQCMnNEaMYG@@A8UIzeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV7rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFrp2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1f1VV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIeHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@31EzQwFkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtHQRb1FBo/kytHoI2OG21H4bPCqQf3K/q1wQ99XTK7vTm4KK90Qlrshv2th6Mmycka9AWD@hjCWl8PgR451NnTkPd01vBX7j1cidFNByjcUpByRzq9LGZwEpYVF371excejC/5jJbceGxM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyR6jsfTr4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c2NVZm9Fh/vTqAJM3JyiAQgsZwSkcirgcvL5B2QOc17IHJ7Suye85kn95uGJiFJ55X70Uwx/en4/UYg2xEO/9XxflSxM9hzOyceeweHo1bqOkrxv64P261/zqdloUTg2hm9OHxbsBdh0eKFslxgcUXT5a88fDo5PAo4ucas9m6Qa80WzeGXBmyyPXT49xSttv156criLX@vBGoGyCPw@daPYgLu4@ProsEHL4NJyMrCPlYtxczpksV1nMmdNJwZeCT@Yy2Ua6s6SHfxbYqzO2u8F4a2EOHbJqQt6e022hZv91ex5XHxhe09gBqEJtwtYQD9Q0vGbPcMMCQkqxtqM7JQvlZQvdoPDTt2cqg0bo0tIs08dJb3Qx22ZHlnLFHoVWhdeJhxTEPfkAU4EeNi3tp3zwMP1DNj7F6cmABPpGwU6lkcvkbJtEzuWiCN7GJJig36fwtxL24YBv@mVcIEINTtP4pX7RUB2NwA4/pCgRiUtuEbGo1NV9mO/jRkApo2EnKEb3IHliQV4NtnvsHWCsV9ZJt1JhYEZl/hDg078tN1AJcNK4JZWLSico2JxCyGRx/ZfS1BXbBaNQOwwQ1n4E3WYkaAqj6B4QBpc3zJwdP9o@Od4@fHTUyrUv/AHFQCNuG3AIzBR9meyKU3ScbaAPcYDUdXLcgO/oSBI72vaBcDEp2pWi1paItCiXuYJrNc9tWFDpDrUiXgJ8k8twoFHkavDjsoMRUP/7x@Qo/zkynsqGKOGiR8oQ6q7DMqozHOvRsm7YffvULNxSKX0Cq4DeQMGPfxjAw4sBxen6OnsFuv4IcH@wePHr2dJ8FCC6Y5szsTYa1cp6boOZ2HaCe@iZtKquxuJ8kDnVVq8UfxIEwcTnOKnTqncw/A59DtIA6eF7eT73FEpsEHygYDytF@c/fUC7jMu6PTkLceIBUHLIFlidG2djYYMfAJOz@04PP9p8yxH//PnkjiRAEO8Yjt3/24x7/gEJgEif4@pM7om6ITIoI0WP3wVn0xXF5pDk13fH6b0DRBwvoUHr4pYTwUy@CQB/SAL49I2t2VyydJcn4EP9mlW@ILsiIWCgwuo5T8WhUzvXYqemZeCQeceijjbdlZsfdO2TXUGa7@IEr/IyWTl/zANSn9oTbUfKtqcSA0@RQ5KTZJiHLv/0hRiLGtzeA2TsGaCjMs03o7yYV9hI4Eae7K9xkgiTV49eSBKAr5JKwV4tEvGYUzlOarvL21/6JMqgycE/A/R3fPcvcg7df8d/64P5V7n6uIKNdNyK3wCWKEBp@9EvAEQnpj7SPfNfL5mYqFoRDW3eBXGXmCKrplKiO0XkO/C6BOF7ASTQ@g0oDdoMa881T8PwMt5VAy5MVRUGWQq1ZpsMBxozv1LtigbKQL@RUBZCUTgOAZDJ@gEeQOcBksgLNRDg1x7UXoIltb28zEYfORq1Q5TWrbNrPs@KLENFNiCucDRG5BoM0kGSRAsLqfjLofFJqEpOi9IqrcRRcPQd6JQrH3gvfbZ8QIksAsTiNDLRBPsNPwE3ceWBJtYMfTYt8TmTTBySp0CeRKykKvmGHT50JsA800sUHg7hhB9ypyntANFHo8Q8jkgFT5Ef5estanEcOvlvitzUZZQAHlc1c7UyjdSt@jiCOEERFXMW@jeesOWnaLYXzJgM2/eEKZrbB/cvKYA3P8nLvXjdfmbhqfBKJxe4e2Q7OETyAwrCEpmhZRS0kF0XK5VYWyS@Rnw0UB23kXEB2IKZAZHQN86Uz9nb39g8@PnxydM1EI8WMX40Gcr@@nWpKcrrRCh3xaLGWq@TeA@Xo8b0HQUUskC5EpDEIfr8k6k0lWUz9IcjFUZKrRVuF4dXSrcf4c37Y/Cq@We0m1CjRNTzUzHvkS9u5pQd0KOtq5lppFbXy@ZtQWsBTIqD3@Inaa6gmkueXjdZ2vWnH4tc5YUVDeB6Tt7ARgKvpbW0qyOzXC4cFCz9ZeozfLfOibTG7ui2Km1m0AIYH@ifOycJGmu8RCYiUN8gGRKQgK0HUta3vkOvoC0t@Gv@kKjcdFjWMFEG4kLmJ4hFQx8HXWVGKLOyQ@iY4hzC2tMyOEBik4qY4A4uBoRVObkwqkRT8r1nwjBP@91pnlZlMe7cSSZR2BCvNbrLqGcBLCtCgUbt7MoXh0xNnzK2b0xr9fSNwPXVA/N6f8jG9wT6ejiBenx5PDVovAcktQWKgZDxEletSICV8o56zFJpNhfwaaNrTL7g86uUTs6Q8NGY9cwCyPZFMg0T7UFVbLDT8iYUmQ592XKQ6W9TCjU3xIzwnHSX7e1l/nS0Q0Bu6bNo9Y5aIn8WTlRbkj/7xs89P40lxFS@RFVrfLGvvqjnaEP2ierMk0Sd@6wxsva6SFuXydSkBflcBc7NowaeVymV56An0qbwaau5HE/cROEGNSPRH@pglpjY3KSczek00E3aabG1JdW6u0mapFA2o4EEBMqOUfXLx/juh23OWUGrABOjr2T18vDbHrKHKcgvclEmSbeInz/ZA40Iji0kBxsCQpEJga8hCMMwAjHgjkTmDQxoMh7jwIMN8K4LpC1A0rewgTajUrH6HRT5ht6w5iuVyxa/QZalYZsB918WhrADYa3Iu0OuBur61GaAZDH9lIbYQ5NclXozyjXFEHvpmagCdWMTEbGC9hgGshQHY7tDFX2LfhrYC@kGl8uz4QbuUVEQWmrsZuGYPlz24lfRwiOd/1waaqbIUNV7lI7qPMBkaFmxzezpo3@4BNRjxikiNRclw9SvUC95U1Ru53k/o1wLEzGEH4B8LbAfg0BhkME@1Imy1sP/Zz/A712JiU1VP2u5pKp7PVOGmVvMszz7cbErSZiNTu7upwyhq8mrWhDG5spW7f2oM@72DgdIURZZlOUXZOj@PP9h6Yj7XCq9ml1m19OpkrBYa8qtZSyzV0ict9uTJF2/ab5Li7HT@SmwmNPre8t7hhajmcKAfq5TZ@U4hGzsp42dLma7nT9gMxq3shL2G66TP8J/cr3sRt47uTv81fe4pLrJYs4kfqRaLoqI04i34p@H@C7j4wL9Rl@vyTuvNm2RD1yezOTNNc@z1evBzhqBBaskjBvneAUlP8RXWpCcNoOgazfqLeQQ9D7e6hmdE5btt9CEblbNdYzCY7utzc/pg8vjLz4PrGV6vn66YkGilUglJalz1rrT1fIxpGe3PfrJxmT5/0t7@s2@OFGMDH4f4@M7lY3QfqfkPNzY@vHcvl0trmsbdT7588ou7u7u5@@n8k0Z@JydlNrb/9E82NjRtW1M2Wp6ntuKNk5MvRC2TE@U/@1G8/eTJ1z2vnv0/v/GmruKtCLdTVgQ5AVeWqeDEewl@KupY73rFXseAy9XYnP7ascD/fIOp9Z3if/ne4avYJFbXlM9deE5ir2KFUow7wQFv2eDtNFaPbWO0wmVsrtRqNXAW/8u/hfT1jwEOhsy34VbPB7AK81hdqlGSi1i9AA5V0yDf//sb34hgyMVEjdS44LrLGnCJuaIm7rTg2qJrW0AzglJGUYJ49mQ4MRymlu6od/DFhBd42AbaYzcmzRh@BJgd3mXsaSOVSrXktgSX/BzniBRV1ZqqegekgfThVq0mbTFuJzGbzd9BW89JmtEaONBhGnfY5/8QV2yVZ/XnBvdUiBU27r64X69DobL17FY9RZffkqhRFUui49wVWZq9iMMQpNF68Yi3HFYXMyVNTKfTvDnNkFTSbMFJePF7LBb6YJNlV/2WkkAU3zf2/vFi@3j9@f/259//8@/R3/fp9x/QzqLdM/vKFkQ6hSZRh@tupdKt18W6K5438b0OfJSplColpX3ZTGyBBGo9ZWrmo4t4Phs/Yij@oQNgzSSlhouyrfvZ43s9tvCuc5961M8P4JHJg/mlIMcS1cgdUu1aPOha/R2pUuO03pJQIapJDbWQb0k8VYBlvcwad6GaRK1YFlt1La8dQtWpIq@44abHnBiMDAsBHX1864uy1cOQxVs96hWrB8nqizjvGy9Aty7EGg2lZVCHEPixuxuVjVKlUNGUduh5/WLV616GYTzxYqex8OLUiS0IGgtZ86pfUBXhCws4mL1PPNCMIhJsFl4R59WrzSO4WSfvlJxrMWl@H64N@KN/uMJXvG@Qj@9NUa5fG6yibmlZJf9hYV9j73cJ0E@wbqfTed3toBqgd/Surk70qT7T5/qkM@3MOpPulHXxC/CIL5OlWDavbsburCk1MfWbxgZ7yqVQi6WCq5m69Xomy23fSQ4Hf5LkzGJC7B/gqquayragf8rADZQycsKYGf9UVWCxc7hab7Yab7aggdZT2yQdW3XJxxIecvtuKyVdXjbAXa36/9v10Fmli7ugcK3LVGr7eR1Uj@f1RgpAPvdByhIjoHK73tqmkDAzPzc/eLsFyouU2m5s15w9@kESuKR4zokXnLstALy9hOzduykZXHcBQH0T2mMyldqUpA3sGxt@XwGRW/VUUCrEIQHawvn5z/mDgR402cvty/plY/vycnsb/rfpfuk/wfdy@9o/PRbXmjiL8BaKlmZDqTeVpi8oWvAuK3X0kZUmOOrwhHiNrFZqNdABl9z6b/NfTi/uoQ@i3JIBayG2xbZiaPUvG9sSYi/efvW/4K/59qvfR32RwZ9REWLn2KyVLRxtlvmgE27Mfmyzx/yywY2/4BV90ONxHT1tfrNxQUpRXsiswuf8E2qpkJSxA247/TYaEpDZC4iKihv0S0zUSgWxnVLnGotti4Ui9Uy/cO2Kx@P/6IVWLsb59Ayef3/hed7jCG4L7CByVcuoknpR5ybe@dc4fmHV9Y9@Yd0lxC7KzKgAVboe4/QQYsA@MUWRJOin6tsj3CGNKyQSDkZPa19Iz3YlnD3RJ7T@1eUzA7WD/Vq5XOeLO5tPqLFs3d@Cuwr/@xtQDtbsQ9xmv9Ydgd7b7GfzWhMNgsekziv8e/Qa/9hxF/@evsI/dvwa/55O8I897uDf8Sv82@3g3/EI/@69wr/Hr/Hv2QD/ml/LZtWquHlOpEmpZfVycyYSiaqxnXrzaxN3XrEMu2H2Wv63brK5MkvGml8zZvjF8wr37Md/@t1vfjNeq8WlOH1BJKc6LlOTVaA@lMiLV@/GhViNbaqbasbKdDNqR@2Aw2QZl2WGmaHag@FJW2UZg2XmmTnLjBy1By4D/jLgMjN9lhmwjJ2xISKEgmvSzkzQ1YfHAP76AMiFPxM3/HXUTJdBRhaqavTxQQQProt2U2iwOBNfGDDClFU5IxfMFn6ypSG@eNFUtlpaucRkZCq53XjRjLfQhrdWzrHO3NhovmizmAdj1GpMaTYVThMoLpHs8rLd3v/0frutYE/TfOwcLv4PD0fR1xv/R4fO40Nn5MD/4eEhtA6jnrqbAhl8924NZLL/2InVqzvNCkn2QLrHlO2dZj0robuQAoGtoV/qPa8FRHjWN5pC/CyBw4szHGFUPz@rnlbJfRa8gqNdXUQIonGH/4TrDHqxYMRxBtfpGTroDZ1nnzdDF3con5@B1@cMxlbhP4zhoq//Ff7N/7b@Hz9jSZZotJKJ88vtBF1J/Esmzy/PL/17PZlI@C@JbfhDD3jHJOeXdXRSpHNwNRLJVvLykvvBPZHc5gDrkM12ndIu4oHkj4VZUrb8lviv@4Ss/asZrzKQODR@zmeoHcXEKtMXW2eazVkmk6x2gs8R4EKwfkH7E5JV@hbdZqehtv70R/TJiZ0kRcrnqlV1i/EXLadVq7ngrViqVkvBy2YiUb5@1TM7agGGGLlcMlmtwstOADYDr5C2wd6kWI014d66c4dnUtIuLgKY2VwhlVEzmDrIKQ/ZGp7e9aXr@cEhfa0BREs@hp9J4aIkkaFvveD3xOJiRbxzJ@F/p3xnN3nnjlbOXFyEPuMxeKlLXu12z3TbbfTPXlyIbZG2upTz8J4pXVyomXJKjScdN/EpfogOskpIKvtQq1OuZZDZWq4IwT4C@e3tQq5eL@TAp1CKJ3HZvIHotwDfuBivirFzKoNaKnIJKFbRO7oFCNoy9gDs/DJGFcpy@WQCRGkS1LzLGP65YlP0@5Z8PgmUuRR5TLVc5lGTLFdIlFJl/6@2AQNv0GP4Hypj2VRuq7h1F9Ra/PNWjipQJlfPjZp6WTs3Kjhxflnt@p/0RYsHxp072TKQqJSpNoV2@/7u8W67XRNFEXUhuKEnSXcBDUG48QaVPF9ucYpUqnepmtVSnkF98jhSHHoIVgKiK9pWXi0hkQSzjwZNgCSCSjTaYBuCRk@8CWVOuQ3whBELZN6Di/VYhw3wYgOc/2Qms@hiFuPhdO92w0gOv/zQ8JXS4hX6GOEl@K0wy1kUeuwnj3b39o/T2rbEYtqD3b20dvTsXkzF1/zinYKz@P50f/f@4TNI8OTR/u7R/kcHn@0/ewL@HjtbXIHQ9@@LZ9S14v2MfS68dF/rhqEbU8Non02nZ6/YS9Nsm1CZ1hQK5Qxc5hltKMtYX5SrCr@u6ekvX@rumC729offfvvD/@7t73z37e98@@3vfP@nX33/2/D7Mfy@y5/f/TflPN5/@tU/@923v/074Pkf4PdH8PvJT7/6jW/wH73/Mfz@U8Tvj/1fJB7/CQDrV3761fd@9NOvfvUH8PuX/u8H13@/9pPVv@9/a/0P033vd2@O891/C7/f47CCuN/9be6Hz2vxf5vH@9UfvP0X/47//6n/h87fefsv/hhv/ss//cGf/qe33/z3mlb603/99lvfe/utb7791nfefusfa29/41@rmejtd99@/w/@6g9/76/@8H@k/x/T/ffe5f/tD/7pX/yvf/G//8Uf@r@fwO/fgesnf/Hvoan87R/8EP@/9wd/@0c/xP//@V/97R/8@t/@yv9Ejt/kjv/nX/4bfv/rX/uPf/Nb3/mrn3zjb379J3/zm3/wV//Hr/5fv/Ef//q///2//iffRM/f/Mlf/dGv/OU3v/2X3/rnf/nNr9bcv33j/at38P/qH8Dn3fF8FzjvUq739fnq58Ln70ONRS7AJ8Ddv/z2N34JGPxfMPb22z/Gs0LwW/P/Y02lOD/mb/8fcGjXy4whGXDB79fffvu7SKL/AUgE/yG9vhO@LIXwl@8sXoCsv7Ui0S//9Kt//iN6ixmVOi3MYN9d0kqpLRjfbJXLfv/tr9lAkl9ahhYC8HP6DkqopbDvoGx7@8NvvP3RP377w998@8Nfwc5bypXTu2lJvWXBCyLm3yEeRiy8SzyM@AXmn6JZNCn1BbyxL/zAL774QmhfKHgo7e4F@H5BXvxiPAgPrflBQRj64yk2dsGibt@Z8Z2bvm@YM2ONFy9auKQKfph7inSPrUA1ymfZLBVMSrNZMDmNkWZbfJ6a8bnbGQXPBLwt/hfOmcBSi@ls/IheOKlLOfFofhbcKeQhm9RsFpkVJ72HMOQ@tBRM@ebKDEswm6VmMAgGB@SQgqB7oI7XailMWOP4wCtHrV5ihEoqVYNyY2qeJt0uIYjZPYICKWupp6y9VZvxhCmEVw/IkRLQ66moamKqVLsPGdZm9xnCQuAE9sWLWr1Um9UR3BtOj9QsdY9wQmC11Kz@Bt5rBBPSCbH7bwCVUi2VqpcwQywkr550m1dSngpHZU@xlF8H8MQd/Tt3GftQVEtimyuMSDAeG@@pRWyMCNEhvJna8otD/4GTfltE8A3Kys@F8fAd0k13uLqKEQCuJMmyzOCHa@w77C4EzzioFGULjxSHkCKOIA4IPRhOBqWEFNVvil4g/1ht670vBIaF2dzcFGJ1MSseykQ6RWHuSYWON@COPxxeVJhYKIvobdBZjwAXSF@l/DfjuHYWZxww@zDFf3fvbrEPoZj0XPgJTEplnZwT41C2UylRA/h1JyU8h2GJAHxKgC4EeVajtbqUkE4zJtdiGMYODw99JMjjeU1IAZtrWRXfccVoOp3GIIUsp@V02n/K9CQP2XfIFOo/5U0kLn2pmWlargqjpypDLxYd6qgwBEbPN2/eQK3QFqrKAQw@mb@bSsuVKBA8uG0Oy5oHZ4K0XFngI3OmFnKMJWg@Fa4kSwoswbaSAt94z5EIrkRcK5XiFA@oLye2gs11BZXYAedSY3VENLj4kLCUTwaBe4ds7/Dx4/1Pj8etFhMM@vK00R67TtfwvASG7X56nx@60MqFZKzRQNDHFQ0FjLBfyZAwPrj/9OCownih/SpIEGJVWjr1i1lWhdh4/Pl2zN9cJOLH0xzxCO@VRdkSWjkLSWN1IdY1cGSBa@JV2lRSFR57g3vODMb0aVFMqwUc2SVpBpkJv@hMGZr25HZAoE3hUQx5e5soINTPJVqdQCfUVkGo1/1teUwV6kf7x5Dg@JCpWkYW6l@wmYwZSpdC3apZhj2YDDdxf5vYzIiRMm02Mmn807JZuKu5QlrNF1sbG9a5hHk2qdrOcaPiJbyeS1iMD@BiwgcC@wC84II8cPch87d@HhxW/f13aEQrwTfhiWoemllSwElrDk4YR68qcPfyWo8Q2/jyywmr12F8LR08EGIgLYYs2IImmT15KFM196auQaEDxnrmZyZ@FU/umd7Y0ufQdIAascvLyz5AOnjAtLpGrzxFD@@XXfLpgPtypgsxu1KpvVFzRUE7qVTeZDVNAA9hS8E9bhvAALRVYEvhf1UPMslmSwpIKlUU4ZHNZgWcKBaEiiEw2g/yJlOrSZwHszmVtoMI@KEFfVbTwsuPO/twETeb4XExBALYYOKyTBBW5GH@W0GgNyAaboCjz/pW/caZuXMni5MY2VwmnK2gErNLqJvNbC6LFBf@/wvPWPGlm@1xPZtRt5UxOHVw5rYVHZwdcOa3lQ44TXCWtxUTnNN6Vs1sK9O6wIRtbkaToZWOmjgxZmi1l/uJdc@w@jIeH6qJlIEmbvtmqetBwnqv1nO69E3uak828dvoeKaWJ8jlxKpjo4G3Gpp6oFPILJE8Fwa1Mzr5Kxi1gYw2Q1xbt4Se3HF6c9mbzC08iGM5bi0O6mA8CFhAN0APwbmvnWw2V2mwljx2xjuCli@mGmoGOhD8qaW0lt4wdorFSk/uWobu7uQr@VK6h2d8/PWsnXymMpC/ePzo4WQyfmrQwZ@dXBkSoJUttIezU6rk861GQxRTDcqmhV8U5uJJ2tiANm3oPQmeuNrlSVqpBYl7plurxeM7WVWT1Eo2U7oUFoRDmmMJ6wImTWHJ0kj3c18CVGzHBmFTSetp85yoUOn3@5db56nFi6CfS/wN6HMp6enOefhalSLxKmyalsxFIPjofSD3ub@QVxG1fEmsNqqL92JBrLYuhbsjo2fqeN6nmTm/nqoAQplDjUFGTSZcVlzHmVQ6Rt9xjUXErFoIInKErkfIiZdhds0M5nh@PbtCJNLs/DqUXF68DFMFaAmXl0B3Tmwgu28jtU77YhtqOdfaBxEE7LMdmE/FaLHnz4XY1tPPsvU6VPV5rqjl8rm8li0U8kUN@ptyrpAvQWPLFDJ5TQMouXKpXLwEvlaUNzH6OhrbOw/4vUL24RN6hRs4bLRY8s2npnVeykocj0SyenkZeyPEPnz6mQYd5NorAZ3uZ5pUr2XzZXBl0aVlAWEmaJqkZaWsKqlZ/L/FoeH/u8fX4F/DO6TKasIxWj35FLpN6Opt9gitJ0wcduzg93MG7J7RXRNjb6jTpuU91/G8v0ece7p9woPum9zUaBj0UMePiHkjczJcE@PZeIQGUwz3HwzC/qgDCKI45BHuwc21HGdVhCJ79mRNKR@Hxr2BGNy6N0R/evDRw@PI83h/d@@hUGD3Dj@9f@WR9yPl2aP9B8fha5GHBknzIYhf3H/06Oqr/8gdPnvanzou/oQHh89yi1vohWdihRxcy5FCbwLi3/CVFEvQKGAgli8GDlXAkxR3YHB8x3fmCwtnBp2f8wO/phfu7OdnvyvCcXAKWGcoaTsG63K7ODhaJ5t1vi6vFsuCMGa2c8aKGdZzLEvHL6L3N8BzqOOJRgMVWstCTsSszxzX6p2ZPWNDeIyHJ8sqfn0akRAeApDRtEv2DkCZQQuoPfxWOS5LdaypwaZjttYTHuiFTtccDKEPPnOCCEJH1xn83veC9Eb0mtzsMeF5kN@1EOt6dCEmiOKeKD7UJ3qs1Kh6rXE9U6ncuaM@ccVyVoQuWfcGxv4MuJY9g1aku/N0SZzI4gPWHuDChlVQHUgT02Eg0gC1vaw1Wjs5rV7K5P/6t378d3/y64OautXM7GW2dx4/guFNvgLyDVRZRtqqr9HKNLbRyqV8qZzVSulSuZTLq4V8Pq1qaRgWFsswMsioJbVQypfVdClXBlUkV4bQfLno68NKoAArWxUAa3fxk8jbNDyShzAO4muR7HVCT7KYHr5PmWhAGlHAkeiEjohvmTXoRZmaYdkiA4g667LYgwd7mQcPRPEevuDGjb2MKPbwJV/KZIr3RNGgkL0SqlWiw9OU0LicOOEvmcw9IPWUA0C77KI4xJf9As6piaKJL3u7Dx5gPn180TA9RDvhIfzFCl6KEM3GF1DTCcCrEBpE2@X55AjRfXzBLDHkAQ/ZgzBR/ChAB0Oe8mgcwMOgpLu7onjAX3Z3MWSPip3niH6CL7t0iaILL8D/ojgAx8CFlieKHXBiKxDFLri6cx388PPTaLrbnuiiOOfkQQKJ4oxi690TUWwH/pjNZz42eaRuhV5UXuq79FLGP1HUAqQxWjZ8yYpiLnzJQdkePvxMH056xoBfc5c/u1DShw@zujmb7j/ofPRRZzDouPPd/Y@eYtDe3kNQSeZTtzPo@Ak7bbgcSLX3UNNPRvOrF5T6oN2u6NbKoE/a7ZxuXwlqz9sGYgipXgFm/jXAjEbtPQjae9i@q69aSyaAbRQAI3h28Lo3guc9vcODgouC6DnrdMQqsr@iNBMCDhpwFRib4wkIVDs90ruuU8X3WY1l0qi3zBuFTKtKAWwEyn@meonh/QTedZwASp7PG7NaplWb1Yoa34zUT4jNmZY3xfTGaEct5ysb@o6q5VKzClqpcPpxFpfUHZZQ72y9ZolPkzsaDATE5s6OJDbU1o6mliqF4vOtqSgmK3jfyRYrEDETzzCGt2Sj2Nop5iNJisWUrmiVYhH0MSDKBLr1Dk7MtBOJM0M/SSYRXZwmgCJQWdmcymlW@4lZelbjeLF5sjqrqVVuspZlrsHqoX30aXfiuBziAMDNdjIVXIZPiGq5JEL@ipJIJkOhB4N2YbHV8/OvH58cH39Bel/dn8B4wj/oXvVfP3q4Jx8cBm9o2Vx@gOqo48p7KLWWQrheGngdw0BEfgg9KQzqAj88Deg6lrxPe@VApw0CAls9sm9lVD5@uATnaOic8ZzRmEKVTNXZXYOh4Xezx/RaHVx6jyUIK6Ynz6gPb9frtXZtRPYGoIhBqk8YWUVfgDnwOO6hiQdKfo4n5PyAdi1zWe3UZrEZwGnXmKS@GDm9F1qqW@2hvfd7tXuYuNqGZ6dq1AzXdVwRhtRitb9j16a2p/eNJ4aLxksODjdBo8Bjc4k@M5KbrLmPsfdwuHIp1V1mLzD7dDpK6FK9k1z2irwiaRJfD4p8Tuc4cZvGZbVfY4nnyeoreHU3WaIn30vu5Kq9xD3WToJP5kX/RZ9prJCr0lAjgZCgGRFtsMx6slb/BJQgDvikUgFE/Do@AZiYE4A1exSgJ8fmZbVbs1hCYjOWJPLkqoNaA1Nf4G1bEsWWJDUuWkJdkj4X6tBSq/OYXvOmHfpICMt0VC1TqM7ATy3mqkOoWP35rOrWxlPXqFrw6s/m8eOqehXICVQDMK8vEm9/6RvJbSlf435VAnVhgd7Rltu1WdVGs4PAErVsDQJSjVwmDUN4uBXT0NtrhbRaSGfTubRURF/o6tP5NHjCEAd0i4SVEBkT05lZRlbTqqGmE5kXZu9FMn2SAK2FSMaS6Ymzb09HDHygkpAr6RWeOkumtC0Lhl49h@nbErEpyIoqFgxoPmRjMz1EUE8N3aIUyaTEslsJazOBcTaPp@P9RqtS2Z@Nvw5BCenVTiFVzKReJ5PVxEay5hmvhHpVqKNcoVKPN4Bn/YlO5k1HDahjcKlFrdJodLCIxUw6m8lC6cz2xWBbrIutdGajoEIVXTISGIxLjOjcH@o6C79xG1Vvy4CqU8taVZBpIi5b0qSykt/KZ/hkIE8pjH3BhpRkiaYYHM1OxONFLR5Pxqu4DLEh@vPOIM1IksVBrMbvqDsiqGFiRSxrGGEhFOn0bSbADhSxSwFnP1gORrbnwuX55XZd@JpwhGcqt7Xn@Fd8/nj3EP@@Bl5leC09f/zs8NnhA4EptNNTbseqG1W52q7CiyTX7wqxCmMgQ5u@3Shlg7H33UOa2q4/588mng8AuAKZEm6wFu3tMkwctrHP0CbBDotDGXR31NC0bKuhFaHXAzkaRNU0tYqLNDE8gSDXoTK8c8BvO1XH43yfsPlcT0nBWP8OY4PUpkDkiV2dCNit7Q6e7gbb03b3Vk8XbM4UnKFugsKO29li5/FY/BL@hNhdOlyo8cOFLBYeL8SFVX9NJJsrsGQ5WLL4WvxuLB6P49pAhXlvYlRvwXGtT15owDIx2wk8YMiE01nQmeXzOIEeU16MvS@1UvbxwaF9331gMH56q5Rri/UYy6gSHoKqVnzfvNjeOFGBY7Ji9iQdY3djtJVeLJc0UeMe1Rg7keJqJZ2GSm5uXGw4uDTCwg17b@yPv87YOJ7NxRlr1mKzWs7f9q3W65K6raExtiKrgOzvqwUpc1HnPF6ngIIGIW9/6Qe52XYJ3rWMCu@alk9p9bq6pbFkbPz2q99Huzrn@5/tPmJxnFD/uz/5kVb8uz/5V7TnLH5Jk@xathiDmOhUC8XY@fn4/PwSLh6Wj7ViHKlcMQluvuCjxuqKqmVt266yiqLrW8VUTrtrVxU/rlpUkzFPivlLV8V8zLvwg7RMCYKCtSXyEgtYA7H9p2ZeU@9u70BxdrI5rboB9a@Gh0tZ@LdteGWo3dLjFxeMwUu33hsMTI1cisIqbyS2/UbaZm9wXeeNtMFe1Oq4P0DFI6nBuscWHtHDtb94PaVsxRkMjVi9cVm9bKVo4QTGkc8NY8tuXmHY5gae0Vj22rLhz9jy6A8TBR4evAZvxtZLT0xsJRWl1wuNt20bLF8HrthSALetYPGD/0lSM/n2l35D0wp/9ye/dtG@aH@hwWCyXC6oWuxnP9ue2lPP6NV/BglvMJgSDAhp5Qgtm6AjHEgybhXV9FOFDrkLY9ipjUozjx8MK3EgyUDhMAe20aNhpXCKShJVZJvb7OslKNoW2lNIk9JNNrKSVUEIlVNSqt1BN00w2BZay2y0ksK58AEGQU/MQDGvCh8sQIHHCPpep9v2rKk7phMtCUqnttLsDiSBHD5Ac4gbZAfCF@MSyDNl63pSjrJHVCOFio0Mz0PjitADCR9AEt@ksDVnYx1NlmBM04Z@Q8YohCcF9BqQdwvytniCNvkmqPQ8Qppx7HgiGxRv4QPQJIgKJigYzNyGCFWQQh8AAaAMCR@w2WLbLJtk52YqVV1YbrzEjfloW1IPzCUImAyh9dA8R5C4ivHACxR@/Igl8oVfw6DbRTwDIBwGX8evwZABk9Mbamxkz@SdQQEssh2WoKKxO3cWWNVqZi/JqEQI/8Qc46wX1YO9GlcAFgy3PuxVxDRDm5jVwDdkO6B4itAFrpO4McxqJCkT8fVSEOD/nZkWOfJKVVFAFQvg1xdvFV0gGSRGsvM67LLtGlO1YpKFyHcB9y4hRafWwzFkc/ahrH0RBF4Chj@LBZ@IARF1HJ1J9Pn2qr0MBlr2FL/PgVbTuDDw7Vxwu2go6g4mQeowFRTFtCh233RhdEMbDAKTjImsmsRkCxOWhAdtnddyDHew55P4oFQYm8FTR9OCfj4bZBKp60CFemPHJluEZCsJjw8AR4CM8s24cbSn9hl@z8mvG0ocxcgjE27I@Ygx2VakD2FTWlzh77gwCA5ok2bGQGbdUY9pZZYgRiNzc3YILkmJCOEOqMpI445ljAClI8OgA2ZeRVEGoD5NO2Rz77EJfDV8YEJ/Y3uK/81x5cw8MZVj/B6F5PTxHBq3YBJDjQubH99M4Nu3sxznhFnmicEniBNL9l88BoMF0HfTQNnFDwhbwV0qWjaNsxVqmseCXxEeRe4spSNpNxLz5PVnVt1ItLFGL6jzMV38nvipbkfoS9eF4I@PvbkXWJAiO0jwLoci1/Btx9TiaBUiNIok@LawamSGScaFh3FCjImBDSl0CmPXOGU40hWwjwGh2Q2ssWArhtJ@QB0AtT1oWWhacuJW0IYQYOL2El1oer6At9mHLKsJGJEb@PKNcQEMrPraMnQIg6RYDm/Sg4qRabYd5Qq0zlEPwtB6hc9@mD7gbnST2c8Fe7MNHxx2OpRXjfFmEbzkIy/YOpCfqegbEFgADFdgspEQUwA2JSZFDjpMfzU553aBZEmFXYeUZgjBJzVAIVVBR5FDn39ffHhJgIB7uset8/uGJ8/OzmSyhjp1Tdnw8GNEnmPrljIemKBAO8rEGI39z76a@LlvH@7CJfFvkMnj4XhnhqprrXxnzp@C0Pdq/l6fRLzvxbFzPMVv7QxGZDkNTZZ5xFAPTPpOVzfhbz3i/Ke10ucB/1WQ/6RS/BKBMIZgZul5upsGYOlO9yTdP@tV/YBTapAAHGrRCDzRRrEbvIy8wGWO@2EMZ4JyNAzqWCe0fAuQRD6tu8ialzCIOQ9e/fexOYNEtnHGdl1XnycoPImxkYETc1J72By6fQoBJ3Qz7JwbzDVnjXlrKfksTA6dWrh5wUWzaML5zUC59WQMn/HwGYTPePhskWmQbWPW4ioZel1icZDr0ZpmEBPBzIM4l9zS8CKEIIP2zVQOAmPOl/wu4detUeqA3vwN6rEWMAbwxBgIbiSUxvNmo9myPeNsq5VSBsDsIhECahxAN1pE07Ne6EbqW6fW2PGWvGw0ogq9ko83enWHPjdwXsEyhhVEjMHpZaLdy8HI32XBFQK/wAAB9TAIRNVgd5Iwk9XQWjcFAuM0xAWNOWINH5kWaV9@kO8H6hInPSdsFFArAgj9wyIBmhDCgpbDPz0XSIfPXQfiBHEl@lrWCO2vxVtxoOSVpsJlTZUqKYKVJAVoAtlRXa1dLUoQDlXRuBIUKealX/9R9DfeG/0@tIvV2BPD8g6jKkSbCm5sBBXCby5EVVavReoVMFC2dMtwoefa5/qp31tDNltKMMzg@WARvDNz0h0mIpXfTfL6oeOToi1WQlaY12pQxHmNN0veLgKScoKHyTw/2TxgBD89FyAAI7MymeEnm0WTzWo1LjjYbE2yswiSM0JyxpPw2LM1SLb8ZDB6Ogi6F6yeFminuPNSBHgq70ZBDRqLzNNPDVwLf4m2IXEpwc9zIXOIC3weQhUb@azbWpl7I4J0RGhdAYCMeA1Aj3/FtiJcFXiqFL6FMoqTMpBR/M1nAy4rgMFIBFe5/eREyGQ0BgaFX0xRPwBtV0w1BFGlSWH8y/CfmA48g5963TOzHFNd9sykr/z9g3i2kLKRBhrRPtRMDgUyjmSe2b7h0ajOEcMPvg8d0Oo6Zw5LrFC2wV@Z@kmVjuV0lJGOe1rw25bcVx7Pk8H4ARdU2N2xM9EnTi5X4YMmk9huVf58zGAObAc/iROxoQ66Xs8xPDs@gUrtOgPb9Iw0Q/OWJ4Y/7DD8jzoIUT3ZdzqeIPi7q/gwFkFzvkJVt93Gr2232wnctJishDuwaQ8jsmc8LuD4F1yR9CCefKCH44TTeWl0J8nbYeIHAfxkx2b3JHE49gNxlnSXgQzrgv4PoUPQYJjnLEaOZGwcVenOJEHfwRg6I2cAWt/UkwVMfQX8wQI2IqSPx4RLmuk4pK1EPgtBrSTRTetJP@kn752UfaIl9GSYXlsGsESMNHOv0hgp667Irr02O54syO/o/fE9iuJ7dDO@NAq/ijMfmtd44PtlnU0sIEDEBRrZ29HAooPc6l1DZwmV0Bv1Kp7gnVHs0Z6xHmK6C1F3/ehyH/gjHb558BYi/tk6@t9cgUHy/XetPh2aPTuag7wZ4fbLBH3FzAtWRhMQ/SCJsud6diFr33/HvCAufkDyAaoQoMaS4LLRTjI0zDEMu71wujgAfAvP4zata3xPe7dqPHAFTu5pmp1o66vofrtnWPrc6CX8mOkI3KDET2HARvLq3QqOgo6EnsPHegnou5JhKHTjSHQeqbKGZfT0aTK5nq14FDPkHpopJwwP1tMPw6@JZpziq/HZahgHxOMxnI49NXH6czwfz7kpfot/wsqXo7z/4TWJJiBuJwjQgfeeanqRbfIm8fk0ERbpHXqEMK68XGS0lB1ARDNK1@vw/Uh0e0mhciOJakEtC8sfoVld4@ZNNR7hioAn@SrTu7HkbUz3zjwXYTUObCHC9t6vC7kGGTdzdLuJKETuc2ONOfY1mYB@NE9nr@lV2isEapiSJN3EpOE26RdJAUfGB/DECafP4IkAB8akzRkqKBvOaflfhWQUMtLHEa3F9wElHaBEqMhJ7qMRiSUEboh@fhnm2V2bZ/dant2lPMMWsJxlJJLQXcrSrwWsnpuqwDL6kzXSGYNw7AyPm8Q2XLajuzhbcR434xUzzeKn8QoI5LgRr@wnQCjHe/HKfXJ48coROU7ilU/AsWhb8Yt4JWgWGMGFV3LcRX9fhON7N17ZSyQvhYl@YnhBvnK8EtYpxNnhr0QRIAWWG7RGXGKzHb@YE9eAjo2UyjRDjvHSOHyieZg0/TLwzz8rRR@cwUCc49yiyCzF1KVOI9Jj8Hyg2wg@aLCiJVf83nz/8AFthgqjYDYpGONF0xB4UMNj8WVhxBHDUFrRgCcgiHKzshojFunJ3hEdP3fgUKrk5fyJejLpA70EhTcgcmuRCX1LzE8f1NcyCF6B74YnJl6H5zV0guwII1yTTa5AC4n6In5DobCul3Hxaz9aQzTXvRwJsJWCKLyWCGxEpoMOR4tzmNnYGS8zCYXiznszmoYm5XijRO69koykgt8y1wSTt18yFAzRxp@8qTiRdIjakgjCwEamxVtZ2C@QLMaghayLaKq88QEKEZkDLdzontB32u77TorHxU2a@op13VCQlmdJkmtZTEJiGU1aTfUJzz0cvO6joav3G74GKWc415JAAJGUYS5cvjrvob87XH8PFOqACFcyWKVYr@5Kr6vXN/ayVzD/f7v71q02kiXd39RTpCXcqEypJGGDMUK0BQhbe2PwcLHbB2h1IZVAbd1aJS5q271m5sd5gTP/5xHOq8w7zK/zFPvEF5FZlSUEdnfvc/as6bXalKoyIyMjIyMjM@PSTZq9O4D46Kltd6ZyFLeQkJx2B5Zm/hCv3VHxYfIhSr40GkOf0vYN2eI9wVfoNr23EFjQEkbX6Zcfl@jlx6X7CXVXI@le@0Zp8dGShiMdjzFNuvYwrtLxWUOML3y@HXR/9wCP0gNsDx7gcQdGUySXWT666rOVSzK3SWzLG4jU0poSQc7XpfEwJy9J3PPVbXxtSy/2Gwfb@3u7H2jRff78uavX6EmCH2YtzlrjdVwgs2V1vB7M2LYseUimhMtuHMdHl4PR@NFpP3NHloiwJmUgoFYM@@k57mpZZsnzqblL9aSsRVEN62MyDYKUVIKqE2DJ7mi6jokg4Tj3JNBAjHpL9PZ4t@Zy2qBGox/0wkaDly@T0VavYhgacyPu/i37qHAVjTirtOS8unEcji2htvfV@9fVI3X0uqZ2jrf@qj7sH6v31b0jhBV4e7y5W99S9H9t77CmnJQdJfIDYkNJdN0OmyGSvqqlYvGZYshbg@FE5E5uy5X3h0FPvR40Q1xTrUdB7@Wl/PD74XhDatVoOzrBGWaH80H2OmPYW3ACQ9rGQrlpsbcgXAEUlT2nPW0Pe97eoNVpd6isg73vsBNGxsFMdTs0giRvjY@1J0oSchWy6RDnIIUF1g1VD6g87m4ITCD2VyAxSkhyw5avNOHi/343BY9qB28OFSJUbO3vbdeP6vt7h2pn/4B@vv1Q33tF9KwfHh3UN4/xiQu@2d@u79S3qvxCECj6CqEjfr6Kxg@i4KM4U6X5ETff/pCGP/6VPvWGBq9uAvabjNTCVR/SpxN0O7@GrYWycxVBfYGvJl8VqNx89eDVO1rzVfgLbjjNVTDbH2SOI86fOV9U69waTZYNmm9lPV1p2cuXXL6P6E0UUuiEZQ4pkeNnTxngbMTT6oQqswUbFZx9S@QJnssGNDX0iGADlDFYqShOfbWw4K0zyA1qrdkdIEyotCZGhPoHqr40piZlhymmbWUAFM4O9T7Og0rl@AXxPb1Y0s2OR1JAPY1fSAH1TF5AFa3DdkQt6xJX4/0riGe1Ii9@7g13@FpYPY9fbAa8i13VOMm48ZAGKk4diDgcXU5wJqc8nISV011zlYjLI/lXtysTI5S0kyQT5SqRbduoZIaETRtXDdrsTbI54ytxA@yEgvY4UrmK66sjGAeF/Y6klrvoBn0xgUpMd5j31CpCHlW0W3YnTsnG7iPDATMg0kGm8YjrbWutMPzWelRz806LgbaR5LSoxgTtawhs3kHgj4AhQPnUTqfJKxW7sgLMoK1ZORcNiCNxbvubXZ7YuXXVDFMVtNVW7ufOr7@6msheap9k7BQZOxqiX8MRqZV8ldkejGiOs1jlJFaQgs3LwXDckTHMpXvAN068zFFpLGzU2k@VjVRroMN0i/1B32r0nLj4nlbPiSm/pVXmeLk7j8VXkt2YOJ8WYbG7AzrB@eA6tO7OPFwi3YQ4fiFFmO/Kcfg5GTMmon86iez4TSEp6mplY3vzNP/bTx4yo4pYkMTExugQ/xNjoi2aHnzPxwaLI@hdeqaZjHbR1Tlqaxs8LS0xyw0w2gdedmhf97JRjr@JufHd93CwmX7PLz9/rkitPCSTzmYdXeYS6eapE9Okx3XOlDYBsWQnIUuyPmfeeAwzltcv4VSDUUAMnz7kCPbtU/nitAgxvTu/apNk0Wl79XDH8F21wRYVSc5zOMvY41H4MbdZWdxwC4lBibLImTMi2jOQS65rmaXwenUH3PbD4Eh@fzu41Qexk@Xhd0HbfhDa78Itv3g/LFmWLFjfDva3B8DK4vaHwFLfvfsByyJ5F1rM6TFzevPZ2Jr24RZ/ujN2PPcIDNZenKDEQK3Wrvp8RW2CbuekgmuDSRSiw6Pt2sGBysj@hOqS3MOWoaXFIGA/Um8Ta9tOn4WdHytN8WY5Vp7Mm5RFW@y@9MBknkm8e0SF1kE8TY9YWCShvdudW5F6emVhFYKt71kgGsqlsftkZFB0ogF/oT0gIZsMmtVBZ2Y3s7L4dCLbCFzTzRPd2LbhZwtrWbuRDHc0sQHZNkHBBTxLZo/fe9GP10w7omAh8BE63CJNmtYb2iccUsNDKuj76RF8YFjMkMLIXhTsrKEdDL@KaQ37zzMUM5Io4aILW2JdK8caNdGP542awwaJWAYCWHrqj2LRTB@MiOc36/aAusmil0svQaRkIj3qS5srqPrZF72EMTXidbISK@T2XJtnbE4Mlmc4ndWwy/cXegxb6JVp8TDdFEnbB5vK/32aklUi1ZKh@czOmI8EeWV5@enXYE/3wlTP/1nYsoZMy89xb0j7@wRkNIn4eJ84t77nme8JAzxAOjGtNxNmqiKpOjPWlFTfeTGy8SNc5FyIkEGkemScnW7VVbdTuM2GLiuSDZ2L3OmDNYXjjsqsuUP9Lw83B4H81fYe/f72ZLKhEEwHv8Aq/81gFIWJV54V38V6Bef49LtwNOpzMfFn6gFKjt2YHnS2Y287MXiVXuEj37fZPWlr7yQxu/XMWQM3wseLPpJM43SvPH28ly@V7a7u1Hdr6glHrmynziIzo4xryZ5Hnf5DCLAM5nMJLB/sw/c4WqP/CQfPgCQysTdfjmnjfhU3pghpzSect0ibhWrZWpoe/XbUDPqICOJlHkcq431HFfkUtra/4846WS@WU/UJuWjYz1EtL5P3M1yV3uFAF5DSIGQ08d5asOCpYSwl4V5zMYB9FC62wls5PWPLyaBQWi2uvHC4d31v7PVOXpx5T5qVjKLFN@j3oqvRTevjxeDyuq26avjz@W1z8usvSi0/U0@praXvJHxwaaVS4Iitz@nfVfWiyJyrEfyeQyEj6bEv2WCVWlDJPrz8SLn8wJvmNXhITHGpetIzXAgXu3Gld7JyVulXiuXeSf@sDCe/8WJlvFhazOHFd7SKkoyRm/mT8RnWVPvUNexfKwTp5Kyj2jVEsWsIvXkTjDqD3ereq9RpHBQAHIFpW28@UJcE03OwZoPvid8Pb3L6mMxT4FgHCpIzx15BJTi/83kyjmNaHcKMRsUjbTa65X8nrjNX9K@G4wF/MSEZwVrqc@ezM2fcmIp8okBFTjomcCP8CwhOUiaHiyF5OxEr6nxJ1LUSfCddC8QJarI4zJxmMvApBKLal@vkzIn8MGheAglkVP/M1dT6OudXJ1aLfD7FgylHMGKHieIZHnEBQn@GfNuAJlhzj9jtw6Hu43cJD/KGz6jG7CfDBvIOa4r4AvNv9Yn9m7j@OhFACD8nOpevjzi15kWKpPgO8uEC4p2lN/64ZoBbpQzKHDoL2NJeJQHOluJMIzSryUTv525ATqEV/ad7kC/xrzvdiMu7UpxJwvfU@lcEWvKQ8qcN/Okm1XJWtbypZgpbpJj7KjVw0kXbozchTauJ2gq7XUJaaDGXkAOP7N@r21@M249O0OZZjLx8z9/5nk999@W7IJWU8mmBTwqt2YUy2U9JuS8qkxTz7rRVUay8@DTSTZ9UkqRs@aGykT8eNDpJ4Y14KIUr4w/rqQ9568uPM0ZfvjxK1YkZPP5@It81fy/pkY@xTJV9mW4ffx09QCEbz2pbkyku9fud7veOTsatv4DNMkRNpaQ6p1tUZlJVtA@mFiekweGcn6ftRiWBslgyEofnTGZj/WXG10rG97lpNMSL8c7EmjFHLCpxm4tMuFt2WKR2@PMjCwTDBKMpM3M3TOWJrjyxwKLUI9OseEHemeDUtekpXoFf5Gf8YyZ7GjlTLjv745xgfiudF@/mNIFY6D7KzCZTWprAXURe6k49sIokbU@mIc4WEnvWKXDcZig@2G0cgz@K5YQtKIykuEP3@IumdFKgZNj3viHExy/O3wpPnFcB6djDbnirqthmBOyF5aQc3MdhNI4QGIqD1kRXw2EXt46s8N2wC7UOK7K0jOuWBKK1svtOHZY9Ut7Dk3ZIp0q@2gfkGxiIJB@iq4sLOJPBA3ZwA9GKE5fO2Heq/YkcaNCcebokbuahQvANFsDdzoWNhIyczB5QOhoGzdB3SEeLSPtxpKvtjk5Syufp8BtB6DFa0tYc55@uOs2PW69wn/u8VHxaskh2ra@Di/7TZ4mDFRHJfFhC9MDl0jPHse6Gm3I3nAdAT@1ioX9HvBleh/1@6FRpxeCCESmtUTi6Dlu@4xyE8SUw4IKVcTMJP@zB1agphzukdAXEjPASjjy5DiMOw1@sz3Jd3OS7Ms/BpVVy20xDfd1pgYDG46Q9wO0wX1ggTIDQA5V64ZiI8sRVaZT47lnjwrpLDwdRRA3EObHuJmIy9AfjTpNGhk@ynC6BkmuQpLF@awoTaq/ZDeAc7M9CAO4xCQUMAuYq6SEcHH1p/rtwULpj5o49MCNTIOk34LlC0z0cdUj6JgTmUeFqFu40wEev64fqcH/n6H31oKbo@e3B/rv6dm1bbX7gO25clHMwXvV6f5ekS3ybLrfm@/QiUz2kmhn@4FT3PqjaD28PaoeHav9A1d@83a0TNAJ/UN07qtcOPVXf29o93ubbd4Kg9vaP1G79Tf2Iih3te9yqqeYk9dT@jnpTO9h6TT@rm/Xd@tEHbnGnfrSHxnCrX1VvqwdH9a3j3eqBent88Hb/sKbQMWe7fri1W62/qW371D61qWrvantH6vB1dXd3qqP77/dqB4qNBKxebtYIy@ombWHREvdzu35Q2zpCh5KnLSIeIbjrqcO3ta06Hmo/1Kg71YMPngZ6WPunYypEH9V29U31FXXOyX2FKjQuW8cHNURLAiUOjzcPj@pHx0c19Wp/f5tpfVg7eFffqh2WlbO7f8gEOz6seQpZFblpgkHUou/0vHl8WGe61feOaM04fgt7B5cG@T0RhrCsUtVtJjDMINBbItL@wQdABR14ADz1/nWN3h@ApkytKqgAi4qtI7sYNUhEPLK7qfZqr3brr2p7WzV83geY9/XDmksDVj9EgToMMj4Q61Cjx9xrjBPhJY/ErI7hXI@HU9V3VHX7XR2Y69LEAYd1zS1Mtq3XmuY@4vRahyidAc4Mgp59sNK@@@o6RGTKuycys89o4ohJW/vbNVqRdWirTPLhmFad1alQSvY3Wmnij/QzFbKmFZ5fXTQ6/fYAPqZxNTn46EUXHnIFuUi0cuo8kDJLn69whWy20XhXbdBG97DRcL1vqZlC42s19DH4Q6Vc3UckYsDOGwc/a2tC9/UUoTa@0xedbKiHCwiUFOp/J6ZvQS90VaHQCnU1OO8DsDk6iuTa5BJXKSQa2dkRGWKSJvlkgn93NDtwxZwB7zcbOCeFZSQXGkT0T/9z8kMWB@sFSWc57ioUsIllNDq/hqYZaYRDIvA/OiJBp81N@lEYfrzIFe3msOf3LwaDVs51TR0uO6Z94EXO/Ur18/Biqnp@uj4jy9fOOodBZPbdrMLE98@aZEqPiz/inuXwT2PMf1yDjcR8wKkpN8WH1frQMvedVIdFkqd0aAu4V/AgQ@d7U/2h/h67ueLSs/LU@9fxe5lbsBdEDFta8E643hn/eX0mBWiCcSwOIklHR8goFKw6xt4kLnxDBS9R6KbTguUPrdWXIa/rRBJSZK@Crt0mVuNR59bGnuTwq4Pqm83jnR0SncD22ery85WyE4fd@sGTvx/QDoeZ5ahjQ1rHSU/jT9Ys2SLFh2eKFeU7YX9m4EIBBRHE3Qwav0Sch9huI23JBEGG7kZIl9SHiV4mBB0yigNwPHIMv86cmZoBcqmuuuhNL7hlFT8gXYl5QBuzdCc8arf4B7Dj6W@meNwhzUCaxTjwLnEu7S5Y7mV2jKkob244cA@K@BnDxxLGLaYBH3Wx/Sy8a/mX5m1rFCMxZcR85WHnmoTEo2kslLGr6MvMfstxRvQBMEcPozc/aH6jxw86wB2HuwuicXV8SGTciWvinDo5jNadPtGQz5BUA0HVTEvrCqf8rkaK554@To4Dg1izgVFBhhjY@KYBl@M4ItNNsgXsywVXfRJORfAOwClrjtW/iXNndUdDKZv4Ifq3iUqhBFYc5ESodhO34ZgiH@I4FoacKTL9KXow/H8gTWbAX6cdJ0FPqGUFAfwmSjJUoRVtX5konRtz0WDdbiTUtF99SMB8sQfmMu6Yvr25Ff8aIoEenYl58YHDHrZzMwgAJsfBhj1/Y5O0y4C2Ti8zrq6Oe5J@szfMKb1WmKXiDtz8ypnHapdn7lbww1WunDVZDe5SVfVSNm7nPOtpyzS1lVePo4yAc038j8ITPgCJJzxz6aVYrU5zVlHPMiMHdKgla8FpxRGTSC39cu@t3RNlhchMyX5982UIRaA3gM/dfnJ2kYES89x0xEVeidURR8FDMHFsk7H46JB152yI2Q0B53GLD0OQgGR8gwWiK9A5VF8CTeUes6EIGkmsDpM4gxC3rk@k5WX1JsaeTybBoTH2x32JYx/KqZYp4UuAD42h7S7vqzfBhFDuflu3hcUKTw4HHmwX0ZgcS@j6SLbSHAxGpDoG6Dfh6HUmrq/e60OHsB9djXT8QlrPOiN9ImGUfmoGapPs3nmZkQDyjFrUGcNboeUzf3CXeiEsRCU8yW1@ReWIeQ2PbphDx87tYknl1pMv60QTDkvKRFxXK@rzZyklBNUhQ0OmYCeKNxdss8nt4N4hnn43g9FHrP1QgfqtsBVHJrVA8lmgDFK9zzEem2Pp@nAQ8YkGDQVOQGJKlOQgLTZUpTX6uWYnbdeUSaJjInYp9@T3txMzqbGWooYSxtWtE/Ot5GkwQaUlHRo0DhZaWlpmVGZtuL7cuxnjaKHpa2uVOe3HImVNlIjKY6M64knkZvz0AU/6kL/yOMLsoTe449YqKBCGzop71btyjvGDTcH7Tjhq2WeipMm0giGO33jrM@gzL5qjQx32rxmMo3BCO4BmoXNbYBiN3F8Gl/3G1qAbXHQGnYD2aYgBfysSD48TfsSAXYwGNxHnEeIPLatQa5I8S3wZCcOG3/G9ZNkKzRWNw2HONlMYjybVSwkTwSfnMAJMcpgyfw@nY6TFdZ4tJ5WctP8p2@OV3PK9dZ@WZlWWG30A0AJuY8qCQnxIx@yYZDmflu8UOH@ogIXjucqrwL3HYi@F8QsiEV/DpDA2yNwxS7A7gZ3ZvRiftG69FscgHCHQUrgdIh1OlOPXXoC00CRFvoelwJoqrRatqnKLcos4hHiY3E/upef/YOwJgT@BfunpLG6ZxQgs4tom2lIk@xUdZZRwYfPADstolsQkxToXnb7lfsgZKG6noaY/T@6jBlv@kFKkw@zd4UrMyBxtfJDuLtcgkdOYuFhUFtSCy3E7oIJUx7ni/Qwbfs1@lic/LnHl5AyCaUtDzllI30eqJlEJiXenzGttlCWm8tdnzNLSt47aFAErs0zOrATQuYzRXNgDpSPrK661BiMSxpkp6mlTj4VoPBgufCP17pUdMyOzzaJ103W/aggszFahxfJJi0lbmeBxUnam8ZlimjTF2NKMeAjbV36O2XyaiLeVBuZbpTH5Ch3uo1liNxUvKvF4t2TuY1G8hkWvWWjiKcW4I0hpOX5/0qCON@6XIBqmbK8aLDEaEBmNiTxaoKbIFFPp2ynE3Kdxn6JHiyiHdltEO3t87iXqtJGcCXlqPqWCXIKeCNwOp02SS8M2jC8QJk403FhIxQrnrTfhq7xS/hxBhvFBAEIrDvPJOZSc4CaDNcVHnB2gnWvAWqgESURPG7aFQxz0PyYYR@XXhzva4qExyZfOygLpNoZEuwou9RAk429OP08atwzlDilois8gRdyjO7Lp8tt79Wf7QuUIgtTmz9rSt@ihM65aJGzoH/tT4xY6cNKUrpmaUemJ0GDRQHOBdikX3VC2q9D@OiPheFg36GlEGwh5ncOfRV0D4bxXijG1UeW2NUERV5NbZpur8htSJWEo@Q3y66koqi5vXAlAKBhT/UqJICCsKWOPSwEOvWNzXgpRPUZUsVLCtKSXHBU1sfOc8R1E1QWeLVslirNKvLBh5GcCIcVidpkEEdJZZhdJoNBCNxMXq8Tz2f1JSpBCbHhfKE5DoUclTcN45ISAnHG66CYS5aSkvKLmYP74bNlNfYz5m7@@KFpfi9NfiT4xhif50vTX1WLqa6rZpaV01VRNoodrt5r6SKRwbYRjqfDn/mPXFDvkeWwTam0yUlqGts9GRnDaZdK@zf85UuvslG10DAPP9gw326@GpFhJBWV/OAC7WuArA8Ru/9O9NZapBhOdK4Dj0hlnl5xsCFljzWCpR7ew0zWR9uIABWZPO2ird0c7O6mwr@cTY2jUC0fLxWIRTHxuB783ttU4SuoMCunShfZVt1sY3vxl9O68wLI/DDklwJrZQYc0JDQpIn8wupDMEMCBiqJ0XjuyYq9/1W7bKRhwQ4nBo2GTkjoaguIFqBMbvbw74gMgBqkX2J/QQfTvJxXPvptAFE0NxVxDUW2YBF9nzO0ZkQcv2rDPjm@qGBgEs7FmonXLrWx8wgqCzCY8WBy@2P2UmCdnXofd7sBT75GJGJEC5r5MV9jZsSsUpQhuGNm79yrieLSeCq87XcuvGEVsXgc4szCZPBMmLjxi4x@EF7XbYS5z8mOGlhXq8iK6uYj41J7KXGRcHSz@G8AKHxLa31S6FwxzTabTdGFa6vUMTp4Io6clb@beJ1XE5TMxTbOvlwZRZ6Prc7AG6rrLuoCJZc/Dyz25p3hM3MzpbakNGhYFhsYJMVe@rQZczf5xYvF63G5/m1TkNAAysL9LIkomlD8nEPkOgGegnn5ET0TR/muepvXOVEARUXCQrOOu3EGFBio4zuNm5ZebXLVaVfPDxUVVrW7SQz6vqptVtY0Xm5tqm35v4vd3laXl5bLI3G33E73cNC@/qE2CwSeci83L0Tb9pG8V@I3BWhtDPF@ozHvl@UZlfaMcFU6qm3Drp6f//Jf/@Z//@r8KVf3j3/Fjk3@c/BgX8n2/MN/8NP/dlzJ@n2yfLcyfn8wPzxYuyuCyv3HU8EF9nA8S81F/dO5kZRWw3rIdqdlnc/QZXVWZFIC9YPSRpMuayjajQla/jSRzFMvYbDO03ofwozynLbxJOjC9lScksgR0guN4Gp1mCAM8Wm@IkoQL7EClvtytmIN7hIOJC8S3KlkdiYd11usQPi1JJAX44tKKle/0o7CPE/Br1nmle44T0N/OuKH5t/Djm@hic3Crnpzm1JOieuKpJ5kM/ymtvKC37nyhA@9cKUbbgUzGoy/J1QLMDFXUYUWP9w@ca2eK3I4zzyl7AMmEqeDC4gXnxbs/dpaRhGvRhTOHPJxKjkj4kglVsp/m@19oWD5RiS@ZlKsNKwoNvYvhxqwblXh8oQIFkRgCJC33hCBrA2oSN33skYyngnmjx9rhbEIMGGQ9eLXD8x4vaC2a72ub59ReCmmO2Hxe3mJtLIszNKONL9J@ggBfqMh2ssiehAvZBUesvK1ecjfFC9vun2Y@sXWYhGNjmy6VflMWE4g1t024@b72a9GG3HK9ojKd@HrFaiozbfutHKtK76o77gy1uwK3jgn1KW7ti8wkjCgDEjgSs3/t7gzjgwITKWpqWCRZ1kS1Bui6zIS@dk2nAXZ9uTmyiFD4MUdz@/PU3HYL7CVi2EF4gJGKTfnaQacb6agrIyb2RTA6R3bAoM0J1cZyb8bnecinOoXxoB0j7TNkNjlP5jN1JTscBRe9wFPZvcHRKJjUadkizWfc9F3qIUIwAQlMPt30rO4ZhKVHekiYInFX2HIIyQu6E50eTcY2E/ucYEjNVNBhVzAJUuzElAw/p8Zqio4JV/@OQbBRviO849tILWJZ8sLSSEPK2G4zPM3uTB3HtGDPnXjiZBxBNZ6Zhhd0pSsstD2@@CVJ3kWMAN12RnsBaleElRdoH6vTRdgPUovTsOsYR/9CWcm6iPnMqSjFGskxeVJLScY7YEV65I/pKBCyNplwRs5cLjd3Gul0bll7HeEg37EtfiFQnTgBHScwY88QddzviLCcWqGSHBi@qrPlP0Fod4MLwm9yE0zAiqfZ3PePCu7Jj6f9sye50/7n019dxkSLZLPK5lVWX2YbiaXnCq2MBS/101ilRSbU4Gk/XeC0r8SHxSIBIVLInfxYOPtcIIROs0hJf5oVgqSGDJgUHm6vAPCFO2hm01gUss6c@8Q1g5/7vuQqWlv5L8ZQXrjyl7Awm0o@pqd9zqhNoNhP95crcTmJCqtLxWdLpWe0E7oIb/Oj8ArrbT66Og9vSZWIsJ2lpef01xQ3pAjx5TYKyvTylvopaU3E9yTSTkpahOppzu04MVtRHV94gsoTlTlcKlxc3LhMgMtHbPg9RSxnynIsKDEdtLgvh/UzGvTQThBBrk17hwhHwspAbET4CDUPyCb5yn0c6prpssB@Tr7aQuxWBkLDW8haq0V/0M9rZc31F8pQouE1010trhan5@idKZqaofNamVp4pEob3z//j3/b/yU7zm4sFd6P6O84@0t2ZTUrj/RAv56aX9fZjew6iq18yU4KtAemx@f/8b@p/sZfCA6@TNbpn41lA2tlkt3IV7jK5@zGCj2Ulpao3f/zz/9MfZiXHRtysc43PMWIlQ1FtoI@8y59V3X0UralC4lYYccswBALQ9qb0w8YRt0urRb5mC6rrSquQx35ytij6CWeDbPGbCokJxnGnoI0I6lQQQN5AWlMKNrKst0wZhtg3gRN9dNjfyWiHcBP2pwjbjI23XgcwWRoXrZFNIA5aZH28/KwUfw@E5t3rGWMTUnZqJDY2mlZu/q0TOzwdhCOO820lYSZrr1mcBOe@@BDP2xd0Z6qH3UHP48K18SSvdLSaqGNw/0C23EXhgwpP5z4v5IiqJMB0caQjU49NaIRGPQQwsvjbEGk0O/Ed1ImnyRp2cOwKWdY6ZzEVER8/Dy5HkZ3/ESVzvG/pMAjc6ZOBGnlSjvtU839gzWVWYwLSjne87rA5i0bx@oQGHmxhh2ybPId7gNOB01//Orogp2QuBairksRP2i1GoH@lnPmMiZVmufMXYbdYSXTlvDuiJ2KGxNNf1Ez74WS7@AEIZ9nQQdYvXAc0Ba9kuE32I8nLSBMir5rjUPFJWRt67J6V9@qcNaVB5q@kaZvaEShJSTtxDxjRWNTdjGRLRUcVY7CBq7UZjZMrUUmafPI5z/AIJJhqbfhlqC7wx6QRLWkO9qqzB42j/fCxCM3ofjsydGiZK52sonzo2dKiAc1dCe060tjJCAQBXcNFsr0@1A8IComzWin70g8v6nPJr6HBsN92EcoUTtsnQQflWWpf43cN50x@1IqIoGOK2vbYDuyesSg4xBbcQraDA5eMi5Yqr3Gmy0uaIZjjdNAm5BQmYycU500VZxetq2z10qiCHqRKZaWnj5bXnm@@gJZzuZ0b2eDQSUfu4DhZUAwWKPO0SYb7yuVzEJGXiEF9d0mAX0WWFzAwazrxnVN2Ocb91GlVNTAihmGdcNpNKS6Pq5kkAnEUehjRaA9Sm6UyeW@XztBx85OW@5n@p/428QHZIYz4WgDIb01Dm@TyFROTwIOVFgwc1Cc3FNEUHH1F7tsOGgfINpECFtXYXtqaBcRIMaXo8HVxaXNHb4ObXVEE4YIznGpsYN6FY6TAGMWVtBF9YFD3fK@qBh4J3d7AKNcLAnQ@QQ4TTMdtzLQlqaYHQu0CCGyJjxWcYVomY7a7Mzc2R@o2t72NGJZOw0dw/Vty1ZS7jiSGQLIIFev1d0joq6OdsGupFomeamoyizgiihXYnf4AL7STSSitqhiZDXrDePcQ2QpMS8moU2TqjSOwGsGzFLx66Q0fq2mFyCIEYT6NCkWYl58n2OTLMHJHmTMU/ByZs2yEX3TiSIOMKcby7jaopQLcVaBOecegDi3KWakI8U1jCg/1jjxsow2kjmKVzSOBrQZcrxTDWeW5DQTbHUbSQBsZB03tED/63tbntqu0T8777c9KMqb1b@i33GK5/vxLWl8S2uqvmOGwI4Wyza3sJn6BS5KxCxFHTA2QRDCty1ZEcMkakCtvqNpL5P6JDW3zxKuALsGWgk3p6N6kiDQC5@BzOnNexyKg911@N2aHF7dlTRxSBU9LeSI6@GJbdFkLmk1hiSk/AYQS9Mg4kAtCbfPJQwvFuiseQd672IYu74zm6dTLCsbKlLbdwpE9jTP3kuZh9hiSbPF0hrG8SG@YL59kDfOw/ZA@6LFzPEV3nj0x3gj/@3Mkf9vwRy1fwx3PNXc8XQNske4Iw4bzh6dnIZ9MINjzie8BjdanYsOzofa1k90ouhZAFjgAUP4kNLHUhF9u0ecqNzsD4vT6xGMhJaW4Rjwhzr/THf@2RpkLj9uh/9VO5//O3d@WXd@eQ1rzYyR16qdFW7979PjRCXMpV/MHF6ou1LM/aM9XdE9XVnDajpjmP@/9zT//6inz3VPn68hYoJcOEj4@oe5WTSR6uFWvZ6YW/iODtqVQx772VzpYu/VqmRo89DuXkWXFWjr6g/jv6rxX4U04iekocNdRGwbGu/lZXsqzvKiWfIph4KTlfRE@msio1v91QtWsh/RC5QIaT7YGumNCinknnxMbpv8RH9MpG@8@HwrziLbdbJMXJxbG2jZEZbcZIqL5quTZC6txOvKNsdAVltHB7uL/0PI0As@ai80Qh5DexN2u2YlsbdgR3HUKd0ZqzuAfaj3HClW0eRkZMfa2ztml7n7pRoHtphaF2dvEuSqDfd/tJfqQd@wsnLjyIho4@v6ZlcF01yzvZA31HcpNLvLusd/iEtfaC59saYO9MbgPlIF@sBP82KyT1taXn5oDZBaPv5gAhY9Kv/ArPq/)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ua4f7)

Run it on Linux to avoid import and encoding issues.

Maze v2 is separated from [Maze v3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235568) with `*R` instruction, which is [present](https://github.com/olls/maze-interpreter-v3#signals) only in v3:

```
^^
*R V3 >> ()
%R V2 >> ()
V2 -> = 359
V3 -> = 323
```

I commented out all the occurrences of `->` in the polyglot to get rid of `Error: Invalid function, invalid name.`

Comment: It's already impressive you've been able to find so many different languages, let alone put them all in a single polyglot! :D Keep up the great work as always.

Comment: One language you could perhaps try to add (I failed to do so after a quick 5 minute trial-and-error): [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable). It's an older version of [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) and [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E). I see `Pi^26qx}318q` on the first line splits between legacy/new. With `<negative int>d` you could split legacy/2sable perhaps? I've done something similar [in this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204656/52210).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you, I will look at it. I already tried to add 2sable with another method and failed because of Pyth. Osabie probably have to be moved out of the first line again - this code became too hard to change.

Answer (score 3):

## 361. [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) ([FBBI](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI)), 16038 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx @,,,"361_"># 23-2g_"01",,@_xxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  xxxxxxxxxxxx r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hatax#8;s0::&&1Pr"93"pllasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F 1_giogrlop#astd[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML ma5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NYdiD4saPg@RFXoCpJigRAgG9SpFKpVFaqKrOUnVJWlYtkMkESJJECASZASmRKyuju2e11255ZT097ot32uNo969n2eiLGO7Gzbu/YMxH2fpxwzCf/gPRjY8Ox4f4HveecC4CgREqZ7XHExMZCInBxH@eee@655577Oujo3vBnP4vhxZ441nxgORM2MbwJ67nmqeHK7N6c3dVNL69lBQFj7bqD6ciwJ15FiDGVMUu3B1N9YLC@aU0MN808w2Adw3LOIFxjbHtqTz2jV4e3LGO2ccYO7K7ZAwhs4pwYtvnacCEsx9h9w7oYXUxY1xmNdLvnsbFr2hMKzTP2RIeX/rR7wvSON3H17sR0bAgqMPbMtvRRp6czij52DZ6oyABU94TSLIeUGHvsuJ4BOThdw/Mc9CyDp@6azqPdTz@6El/NsI90QGpsGbMr2asq@9w03N7VFBr77PjBg6u@WfaJ5NjswXWU1BzbnU6cg8lV@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBhaAmBPDKmVKmatBRahPY2J2l/KBgAemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2ZkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGPMzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7QkwB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/n2jMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPhobtMzOAkwHEscOxejkl1IwFz@u9HssAHwMeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPHBeoBrECjHxgxNe8jMYM6gyqqO9UWD6TgfD90Aex1S3P8ZFZRg0DbWirVGcI94nrDFx9BNToGUTTzw6eMK/ruPAGP4zL29NNYLr6hG1vs/j@p/fjrB5Wi@x2hLCKauwcqiAWBLJT3ZoCh0RrwoH6ccPUAlZZfCNeYXEgi5ZhuRzLQbMtMS0PRFIzZXBA@9eyKvwKTCuxnAotKB9PYz59Vx@YlsGhDBBKERlfyzMN7pkcy6olHnPgWH0erUuZFVm2xApFVsyzItzLrKxBbgg6x9RyHn4F@AG0MqCiwi@b44AWfA98iry2x/r6yLTmPnQC32V5lRUBIuCrAmStBBDgmc3iLws/Qmv5isKeDIHaQ/0UwEuWeYLSyAgFElahAg9la0shiYgil2fvDTF7IB0QLV9iRci@AJTIAQpAWa0E2eczvCDe0LAsP9nQw2SEbTEDP8C8CHQoAfUzQMsMErMIP3gHeaeBYNNAimkgmDQQJpoG7ixmAfEKEFaAqiz49Brq3glkxPPRekR8kOgARkVqoxBTkUgAAWqLZaHOCiwHjJBFRshnGeAPuBQLDORYSWWlHCsVGdCznGFQNyrghVyigvxUAR8VgUH9q8AAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjikzUJaII2agzQ5cEPFqQX8QTrgDBWyVCFPTSsvmBBw0/JQ3nyWuFMrQO0WIQzopgGuGrCTBthqJQjHtCWgYQmZtxhPc0LoSAeoFWR34EMgRh7wIbgQF9xaMcvpp1vjod5Bac1TdvqYtIDNoIBkhKQZLB48c0hNQCUDYLAVAPoacEAWyJGFqs3mMPtLARow766j4g@kxOfY9FGYocAGYeWQKF7wZMIOxE0SpOOy5ARRZgFvQnfR1VGsYSM3SEgFcMyJzCAT6FsN5xR1AZI0S9l4JI06Lnb90HX0DNdlGBf0BS9Ncsubdjzj1RQ7pwVefRCEBsjLvm5aIQLUOPUJSVV4xj3Ib76Mdt91RtSCRyiXLMcZr@kDQAqeIaCHzpmxQH0hJPXx2IKuCPwN3hMCMmc6KTGk8URz5QhBIkzXHZoAkLICEW66Rpdo7xcdUmdB2C@jWGFa/U4WodyL9FFZNnZAfnuYxp5aVgU6D6PLsnWlZ5wq6MP7seX@C3EIejbon3wQHR0UEMScsAgh3dFk6jOPg5r1nNFy0bjQOgiLPjSxt7HO9DnUXh/klTHTR6AmMdRFbOghR8AxvAaxJkARxGIdsJ5jxychlDMXNAModFgS0j6QJhNzZIBK6UASrPEcIY0ikzDrzIGViVo5mXRIjskVQsnCVUJxj1zEgzcW6EN70y5SDfM2beIg6Hs8VJxcQ@9xP2HismZTh58LneTYV5tldGDEI0QtonVBD2sA9X11pksQseM3bA90NU9mJiq1wPkDpw/MdmZC2UFdgqQL2F0iApIg9JrJXVkgkiMDjU4sZrLueMzAH5QQYM8HmRL0685Lk72GQGsIell36rpzNhtDTZgjiDXpOv0@cO9rYzwEEGzUY915F5onVDJyj9BzSCJ1x8vFXLxtGhDHRk1v78kvsoEBZActoI8qP7L8ogDjMRWBSKHbXEOwdaAUFqE7nhNZAEyYou84Mvr3HMMjZnHck7DpY2aeMaCmAe2svxBGI9R4gEtt0tR6IHn85oXwMUNhZWEwK58LPjJsaDpd4Epo9FB9WKe7rA8jl4hegMqb3u0a44nPJw6JM9OOKFGHD1CJIl/JByZ7Q2HzLtu@wjUQNeSciIKASiWiPvZ1Ox1lrT88ApXBNhZ6PJcs1vxa9hDj9Eru4guMs4TBC3ENDmNqEqhRkpCYTlCUoHQ0u0OUhROUNqTEQGtzp9eLD37R7N0Rk/ph3oiNCmJHkJXQC/FYD0OCn3UdkDy2EFZ9yQOjLnncAlr3RisgOyGSVi/qKyu6DELxNqAjx3ZWQAVihnAxynII1QUx4xFKDd0KmZGai7dURyiwFyN27MigDx2PHRdaBhc6cxqeUZVFuMsf1STCviIJo/3lrhW6jDh2@BPsBSHB2IKxHDUxbKmgruogKUCI8VEHyDyH5xhBmFo9wfLxOyPRz5kJ@lLbNlDj1d05BwLFg@4ZMpoz03VBDJ5iJ8H7oKAzkYlPoU@A8RdKViQHtfurmcvI0XvTjjm7OrTpoqf80hNOdZf1cVTjgtIBjSgR73vxZJX8KWUkSFSc8UShpPwuQkSKJEOVJ/owUIJO4gEImqO53U2IS01MTDNxOumXxCQ4MCHX0djH@nhyFbuX4IdMMzqBdk1vVTaA7luS4C6hH2GCAYqMAboLegY0QlDdy@VeR2cXID1giD7bo9SoZNJTlXNhXobdC/PyCYG4RMsr8yw8t0sOKdKrYQkwOpWcOoklAr4jJSihCB6K4vet6EHaHg8jvYZ7Tm2a3GAJrook2Xmo7EMHkCBkTFA@zK45afvqyp07geKyUasBs4E2BWKzl4wOE4JZIBkkNUSWSRvxM5EnztEE20YiCeXFyJccG1CbgFNrdXY@GbrQ4uj9UoBIQFbBRk4OCOvX86fmybR3taJt9MRIIrY6UJrM7kSsCtD589ZQu4mq8SWqwlAijlRF5sX0BPoa85IvVqjoR3MND9Xfmo9KpIYTiIHPqytJxJP6fguG3pt3LV8l4C5o7FwadQD9E392IBREaV8nCBrttZbKgWBz4HDYk93jhzW/LfJApWPalSUPy@nqFnlvYnQxSPvo4N7T3ae/2F4BwzI7laseipkrFbCrnc6kgT1VcrJW2YzCWAC@374ZNiZcjiMKfjCTnFlEVZp3oXOZBeQ8fPrJVZKAJoTkoBzAjb8rKg2PA0qX0NG94ZVOmA1SKcgyTBLEZdIBC2CGDkQdw/UAnyfT16@x8q4iNfb9ETNrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8ooAFQZ0@7xEpLWihpo2ztwtXNGaAz0eoNV9FhlTpCMt8dPhg/2mNwPqTFRJFUbwJ6FK625OB561pzxBWxQHxB64uS8kLxFGfJlxXErjbXSLwom7ZGvgAAMc6ssMkaxQUzRsC7ntXy0a@UjfkAHonCFf1yqg@1H1fRCN4YBfXxSHvql6UAhadVei1sscKQ5e7rW4@bxRz5Wi31V3k2YsCpZlW6AcCvdGFoBNPQh95oUX6arWP/tGja4h7pETCUEAKMPMsJlNeniXg6EUyWdxT9mCE5liG/DlJPJGJSUWJB5OtctejwWck/v7MnCQySf5UkxAXct/dPdDuB5H9eUCayaBBA47FsWdy@7ho0vWAR2zHcgYO24I0XDsMMgS1aW0xdweOfa2GdPTEosZw3QXkL07c6GPoa8zXNHCkVNHhKl/B0W3vDKS0WsgikYhCBEqh@PJL/VQHci3KfXTw5T50Imo@kwndGbqABJE0RC50dSO@5MEkyEj28VlZwHAN5lprDwKkyCIIFtoXdGHC3UXwSk@SmLKyMv5KlD52rlH8pTO/wlrgw1kLHBGSHXz65NHBp/uPd79oTrR8fuk9lykXgHCQXwd0IXnI6YatdYs3TSwWgotB23CxeYEUmMIAJZiCn3ouCG4Zo8gcgTVcw1evEh87QzvuJa8W5gxDpZd2l7PQY2x8PKqfEAbaPQsHIy5fAsT@HPlnOJmMvYqiQCsfTjsyDFqVl13H0gcKpYOOwbIUFYcuB4c4r@GtSgHIeHODp@CTW6A6zGkGUbdGDgxeaCERRQNLcPA0a2WZgyGMhXG10XCTcsjBVBqlByMEGCsrYdlIANMb0NZ/BvUkctb@QNVKnK/VjJZTxCDaUvOHuBt9A4ZOCeitgBTJK6@sead5h81BSiOkq0BiTN6iSQ6PYV9gMVAkadYUx/kBcUha4Hwpygqi0aspzuaClFLymVxRLeQVGJbBMA10Vgnn3KSRPukOpYkjATzJ6dO8QYQL@15Xt/vylu8IkAW970MoarbxvNm0W6CgN@8QbriY15i3GmorWWXXk2z58ZNV4N6l4iHvBh7Au@QE1qQnWyPPevp1cdbTqXX1mDIZjf0@Rxqzx7ugSL12QF73jGjbwwRKNFDZWoqrYOQ3yooJIQuTCnhDSinQoKCnBdZTEC8JlF5UD4FzQG5FErDFbAYvB180j8gRHHQj35tO3KOZf9RrcLbUGwMRabK5i1Law/nBCfSOIeejlIbKRSHNzow4zqPrHp@thET@wmmQHsZqIQSalQ9npO1wqRiYgFLR8BwkB/AVTpsOF7OMOOgHToMMCSecfAANwqbVgwHIGUjMC7LLC8JzIp/lIp3YzpmN0DoGK0kdc8In@52piwuIZi9aNoie1XgcgEaFi8h1WmnsGF0@y8oTUylgEKizkTFycCoBtCsSBQYVQeerlDgW9HDGGppVRsJlGIAvsbt7IMW6Bp8vkkY4iAKW2mfxiavsSl8quvQauPkG3QoLH6liv9KPAwIsrxnTLIk/A0raiTOiSJ/TfAsG3gvUXWE8nwyhxMBhol5zxoZ9dczHR4SJZJXWduNxEPimnTiPb2xsxCvxejwNrh1wbaNrB10pcO2QSyIXxpPRRSnS5MLQBqVAv1b8shFAniVbyAMz1Bxem@OE3qhUsq203lD9p4bPJFQFUB5iS/gAOPFkrYbOZFKsn@GaDejvkbLvIe8cdV1z7JPgY1AI@LtPgywRAYb3qM27RhXHpjdTZFRzYdBooIqZcOPNRqbZap43e6nmZTyNqZNVvQbjQxBek8RIHrjOdAyKWyNXkUC2JRvZSqvaqcUz8a1EoiRZkJGeTH5YSqZ0TutE3ACeSjSbcSCpT51Gd@gSvFlaSyZDQgEefRNGGZaViMvnJci/k2wlU3FIm4ynQSzX4nGgSxeJ4FGhcUaAM9EDcwakhIYJXVx0TYEEJC1OYXP90hgP5240QjjrBlo2zqAvNgDgPgmU4lEp@Zqnjyp0SyP9QO/l8UC5xck71JfGcy7dBY5pU1nabhL0u6dSf@RMdOUzGQZNcqS7jG/EFUmCnpBCOCQq9mPTwyas24Yz9aIzjSsnQDF38D0eTkFYBnt@0sBV5lgwukOHxTfvAnQWrvdgV4JLVxJfAAsA9Loy/FCIolaCiyWgXdAuDRPkIu1voVkZlZDgoieYm88Xxq/kMLcqpWEZzMgc2I5rSEASSCHQlhTa6CTUmb8r5oBmvq6tS/ih1KXhwNs0QCI@sBydaMvFdWQ9aDyKpIfxOSR5avQEC@RHH8SjzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hB4CSoOSWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEtjhRgP56A6UzjPW0zSt0M33K0EYcgUQewiVhKNSG4a4QZCkQmDSr@R9Pi0UjNE/Pby/z@dOqLPF7hXn0dojpzcFvdIfNz017EGa7QM/mbYzMoEMQfrXJ9ZTx5nwUT68rJuZ4YNmczS1dJrzuTotc2O6rtNxLJoKuinpIv7U9XRL55NQQejuZ49B1392fFSTK5FIin46ujFvnIdcnS2n50F0zZHWW4PlIY8zpriZF7HfCrbSoZjxAwoYMPU30kEdBf5F9A@aFK6h@P4l9B/hJjrQlf1ZBHoNPf2IZYqIG@twF5Hvea5mLtF/7RgsjKdSPK44LrA9VzXyP530@0veWfI@kVA0WQvvHHnzDXZLY8QoSnkeCXfbLcWJAipQnHDT3dp4RYo3ph14criy@DjchDA0rGBp8SloLLh8Bp2@hXoVDFpQRecb4wzQsMe4SkKiG9feWBeUUO/afAY0trHEYwuxDWpA0LkpqNIImwrz576r1IRsx1@z9LhYdWDMT9Mq23W@yo1jKpcP5xQ@K7/ZBhDb9Wqwi2ldNMwpHg@jEVTCDVJQMWlh/1pRw20aHk22C5SkKngKDCdmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrQvYFyCW9A27ygDo4oZrqNXNQiJ@zpsZ84k0PgwFp@47g5BzrDUbJmUUD9Tu@9YPYmvkgHDMD6@wgryNymEW@P8HZCG6Qa74mhbIk@K8jWyoe4a3CtVWr8eIbIFLwQEzeecXZykTy9YA7q8U9kbW@akxS7lidMeIkkmU9e@ulmP66Cuq889wd/jUmO7Tz/6rJFpcQjCSMeVrxKvxVmw5xMUZ1CUcHMuuHCnzsSckCZAOxFMLK8qA1IzWiQB9AEGz6DKwoz8EiHqF8bFoix9A0aqCQMx9@ajNDOSl3Lf0icTw@Y8x5cf15ObrxP52dQo@x1/0aHCMrQyA5qpiWGAYpUdHd/ff/pUBs71EvF9XMGpQHPUu0NQUNYVOqBktPAV9mEvzj7ENEkctgvQ1GD00fbTA1NXgelh/AG5o@wYGG4CPJO4@NIFb1rvooRcQ/MJhPutuhOiUQgsYSShTASsshL/ZzYfavl4VoDjU0RJIHfiTgVoayblqW2@kj3oaEhvhShxPliF/qK2mSAptqkmiXtcc4RLxzDCIqURStBoMOk1SDmILLJWq8r3AEBcHIC5A6SuKFJV0NbgmhpUfQ28QaUhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM39XLyx@BixCWQXvGymw3E9TerzVkjgNfC@SS@xkNp69saa@wTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TJHQof1Vy/uklndhQSNDUUJTMViQQCTE/D3XPs9SOEl@GPNgMvJIJNl5SHQNSc4uLoiGbFNjRENwqYxXxmUw@gTB9MiB0jzy91tHtQNqrf5GEmyzTUEMhlnLK7UYwlV45fSKdiqditF0XDs07ROH1ntCVzsjq3nUCMPUoxPresq@6Q3pthQ1xIHH1dZh5406fbqtiEDLHv6COnnQhLqvC4MSqStP6UFz6ytyXt5EspRtx@hP7QGtPqKbSa9uiSmVSxS53@mY66ICEXBfWPBcEQ2EFPKzJudkNdjAjVMx0B@B4OKjl0XRr@4/Ykt0h95hAqn853/@Rg/of712htBR4Mxj6GhD1401JfXXVpafFF/otrpi@QT51DJ1Igy5bgPZ1V0okm6FjtWgaRFekqD7H@GSgl/jwJt4A63xBjbjmPMVweC5OpNVi2o2iMzuurhX9mPxrGj5BwZ2PSICV4JMgxKR6OKVYMz4EkxkiI1i7Hakgk1TjJiZ1/twOpnyOyiut1aiOcbfTW3Tj5nJ6x3VgKGj3jGNG6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPbWwIu6i9LQGLIE64C8Ht9G5uvi8gK45gH42eK6LtujalDN63MYVnj31xlKHRuE9/kYNYXRDDq7F7@uimP6JqNCxnmqmRbd35EQfOjCKvxtCwb2mUoRo5hUyW3pnjjrI8P25LNxZABKn1k2lMtk1S8vj8fr0OJKk9OXy6tQzucvpsWqOQOH7WSU@i0YF9ne43lKr0F2ZI92StF7EuVaYr9qYcC1quKZJaYxTXNE5XVlzC@pjh9SdWrq7cN3A4gs8gmWEdTPSfrfxxOw6oA6MmVqUVS3oOiIdBonMYGvcIiPcTky3yPYHcxUZezAsxE5cCl2rRYDTneCW0TU89Q4CjW/VxA2xESaRnXWU6jpn@FurPgxhaMrvq3u01yuxegfhJFldS4d@fG13sDQ5iJOPtzDqmekZdFtN2JOViE661kr/5SYQTPtFp/FuY2vPtByPHdH9JgINXKACv69m6CgtTd2WaDI86r5BBgV7HBYVqlsDxyqUBooOt7W1PnX7KPf957tKuFBCqeotEipQfxxb9Z9r5fqJ4p7cVkF0CszF/a0R5w1d7Cox5a@9rC8dDAxw4W51yR5kSpRSVvhU35qMccnlTJ8Hz5@j61hH2qDrGM9JnQbtDhOUS@CYuFzF/nlyy92cW@/dhNI1sMXbChGp3BPLgM6K7teqlGkZ9T1TqJnMu4uovjU1psbKgcZh56WBZ5VvGGS8O1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1mt/ZPhOWGM/jW83ChPdMrvG7arMslAbg/Y9xqHzE3A8Qcf1FAN7Ol6q1aXRmf30ZpINx0GTdnpL2GHI@8qh0i2a0pJ@7hn0u3HExEd4uEGslstkMr4CE1lxWXq5aSSVDdO@NPl9KWPyWeS8iIurbG7EuToPIkt0C@JaEaStG9hT5HJZsU3bmMzx/o7StOM41vvUFAjVnomqGGiWtNX2phq7pu74h0jYYurCwwmPTn/dpAXvbfyxJdAHB803VXp0SeidalPCRc8RLkgtv948fRNZYLotFzzMjXNCfPOttV6X9GdDVLkkF29sdVxDdTqGpfPHrJC7CV5Zzt4Ib1lo@Iu1uLjLl3QXS/GxK0JpPAdimT0YpQyNkUGvN2j5eg/tDviPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vM9o3uughjE@SCjfelNeSIsjRxbBhfTXCfH45TLNxJ6vuuk8DBqt9KIh@M9IHBDWHcJCkXExa4m4YP6xbO1VMXFb6DpgvJFhYO1rMENKoTY@4Fz5UAH8@7UK/T0e3TbVcafxfnQN@hta/bwnq9i7WHztAeGkO@bzx8W9c4gB8n3HDJTagD1oMhbmUbj5e2uEfpaTmW9S70RNHIBaXj9FfitI@HX/Hk1nvBnesdCPAft07e6RMuO9CxttUMjSn0S54zccaGRG/rolo40cPv62RosEj9884g3TjOB4oEz58X/q1jy4HuTMZjerTH1tSjGyWV6MzybXpTn29NoU2RjjuQXzujjux7yv6@FVoCXy1iOuakO8RD45yzjYHT6Q7N25DuGPrENk@UYMqHv77T2BUpYzLpPnrLlgnkdecy8kstGn6Ej4N1le7PHvFuLXTcoK@smqGjY9nSWD/penw2FF2sghPCkdbID29X6Ph75dXUnCyARvYyhdO7fFkCHetw93dPrNWs6IzEQgz7uyrWcikp6aiQS0YGFB51XbbL@9wiTSyb5bd1CEVLSRhF9qW8D7n9vT80O2hG5m3Bf4m/ljYtrezk7OF04F0XmHy6vgcqGt7WT1vQXubIlDX0WbrtP9aRWbMUPOQIzzboXFPjxjWV/I2LKhRPtSTdMeHRhgdU3XTtHJpljj1@Z1J/7VKcv5cJxuJX1ws5bearB9N@xfSMPl8CQddtKuLIcXEnMuggUhdX0nEGHYU5V7y44LKdAQh1yWKLyEHcdWrLym1Cq6s/7DOlLz41BjrutX5kTnCz5gquIJZdtb3oVthfn@qe@fUplGwds6HFBr4M6UaP9uPbCniP9YHZfbhUESGSPoH9nZ78scT@6HW9Ls6Gpoc7mkLHDRNTyHKciZHr2jBuWBHz6rx9aKxi0YD4MciVsVfNrTvjOZ4Wm5Prpml1c0KzrP5z3dBx3SawG5E4m47GU89/rMaB9kxFZ6FHJ@TvnZkAXHoFopUNdWuyeqY6MuUKWpjfKS6c67TxL03LGbAvSxkGShsoYaicr2Cce9A9P8ENOa69ghMp73dc9sSJDsnlBXsFdWtkmWTa5uTm2ZzJBDfnBE8sDO858ISC8gjv8t33hSAdr6bIo9t1/cXR5Fv6d@C8I2fqdg10hvZGosMCP1djL9h9jCc6HLSXchYdpXUdC5oXOKyVTabr2NOJ5E7tG3uFwo29QoXNSoUIG7DE1/cfP0tGuYF2a9@mhRow@Jt61nzhWrth4AqTmTYoYuvl6HLsYCxxn9tJekpbhW9Js4vGnLokru87q8Y7T@bQgbzzgAmE/3R03@jisuGteX/qPHZsB3qjMQjK0VODn/lf2uixOiEme4Sn2oE@vVuzOSKwazohrm3oY6MD9WstXO/SF3HA9/WJvqYrorlBGv@Frlt5xbQ6hvuSJv0i7nVD2mWEHhozGlusZxjeBqVJt8tVYpyPW2ojSys23thxbH4naZuBh/r4ZqkCXQHd3n2hXMaN@EvzAivHZ8tFPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6srtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxyTQvrwbZUjxRhmyGBqBJnuqe7RIv3qosQCpzt5jC9BQd7sOroT5jht250QME9wipsO9/XzjQAcIPwOJpXenvgXG29CyRp0R3dYOGCK1@dTo4KmgDlnzmOiz65XJZ4Z8UwaRHV2hAYBAXGGjLrDEExiNJG/vtpbGUctUNcd0I0m9drmcNutItml0X@s4a@YQvRZz00vhUGblU3KumauONCOaRVZ0Oum@siUtb10DhcYypMnQhTG/Mrlpejsws7JiPWQ6MnCReXkVZq3q6nhDKqyzej09FK6uIfm2/kCWhHb/uH4o7a7VPBE8/B/e@1iBTrhdyAWmR0B03b6CD8hPXdt/vAsHPnG8Sd@cHQLeeApgnTjBYuUhCTx4y0DX1rpCQO3ZU4vPPgwi@65GPRqOSWTaVpIsEtcTQzLsU4kMwc2ul8jhh76UXTSJOjF6km8HAVcapEfB@a8wmv9csYAalY242VNVOGFnhZy//XMVcc8CyQD6ljORxh49lbH35ODR4bE89tSV/dPuEE9HXNPjlgwraKVMZErqpe5G1jv5drSe6U2Ue0eqtPfoQMYIa@jNVzQkeODK3NJj7bynb29UV/S1oyAMNSarFcSHx48fpRZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47OkrjSZOPj1YGR1M/gNbRd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfs@s2l1cJ30XJHTOkjHBoxGgRkfcrsstypXXWds9I7nY@Mz6DxRgnvvmH1hbSE/1U/NAbZCVl5LKGqorCwXcsnIzmwYbBtu@FxXnyfmGKVllx4Kf6zdjoKaQ1Zxs6u1h5tW/K9qMSzj70R4v0Rq5jq3TkwJWsZgiC5F9/6@iKmquo7OR3of6pXl11bWcoRV68OWc/oOS8mGP3iRQi9pAlwlmbfuIy9KIxDdCt5wet73BGdn7TaYmwCE3oWVDf7MsOe6LdFa1k3qRQVS46a2G6N8abzDglS4w@cULUCvXOMLt9SzRJecyVsyPnYjSfb27h3cluCpT8ubY3306TP2RPfQCMnNEaMYG@@A8UIzeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV7rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFrp2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1f1VV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIeHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@31EzQwFkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtHQRb1FBo/kytHoI2OG21H4bPCqQf3K/q1wQ99XTK7vTm4KK90Qlrshv2th6Mmycka9AWD@hjCWl8PgR451NnTkPd01vBX7j1cidFNByjcUpByRzq9LGZwEpYVF371excejC/5jJbceGxM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyR6jsfTr4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c2NVZm9Fh/vTqAJM3JyiAQgsZwSkcirgcvL5B2QOc17IHJ7Suye85kn95uGJiFJ55X70Uwx/en4/UYg2xEO/9XxflSxM9hzOyceeweHo1bqOkrxv64P261/zqdloUTg2hm9OHxbsBdh0eKFslxgcUXT5a88fDo5PAo4ucas9m6Qa80WzeGXBmyyPXT49xSttv156criLX@vBGoGyCPw@daPYgLu4@ProsEHL4NJyMrCPlYtxczpksV1nMmdNJwZeCT@Yy2Ua6s6SHfxbYqzO2u8F4a2EOHbJqQt6e022hZv91ex5XHxhe09gBqEJtwtYQD9Q0vGbPcMMCQkqxtqM7JQvlZQvdoPDTt2cqg0bo0tIs08dJb3Qx22ZHlnLFHoVWhdeJBWw1cPzXsdcJp1WFFqbziaCg/aQqIRq2Ue2nfzgw/mc3Pw3pyYEo@kbBTqWRy@WMo0cO9aMs3sYm2LDfpIC/EvbhgG/7hWQgQg@O4/nFhNHkHg3kDz/sKBGJS24RsajU1X2Y7@PWRCqjqScoRvciwWJBXg22e@ydhKxX1km3UmFgRmX8WObQTzG3dAly00gllYtKJyjYnELIZnKNl9NkGdsFo@A/jDTWfgTdZiVoUqPonjQGlzfMnB0/2j453j58dNTKtS/8kclAI24bcAnsHH2Z7IpTdJxuoFdzyNZ2AtyA7@qQETht4QbkYlOxK0WpLRVsUStzBNJvntq0odBhbkS4BP0nkuVEoNg7w4rCDElP9@OfwK/xcNB3vhirioEXKE@qswjKrMh7r0EVu2n741U/lUCh@SqmCH1PCjH1jxcC3A8fp@Tl6Brv9CnJ8sHvw6NnTfRYguGCaM7M3GdbKeW7LmhuIgHrqm7Q7rcbifpI41FWtFn8QB8LE5Tir0PF5siMNfA7RAurgwXs/9RZLbBJ8oGA8rBTlP39DuYzLuNE6CXHjAVJxyBZYnhhlY2ODHQOTsPtPDz7bf8oQ//375I0kQhDsGM/u/tmPe/xLDIFtneAzUu6I@jOyTSJEz@8Hh9oX5@6R5tR0x@s/JkVfPqDT7eEnF8JvxggCfZED@PaMzOJdMZmWJCtG/ONXvkW7ICNiocB6O87po3U612Onpmfi2XrEoY/G4paZHbcBkYFEme3il7Lwe1w6fRYEUJ/aE26QyTfLEgNOk0ORk2abhCz/iIgYiRjf3gBm7xig6jDPNqHjnFTYS@BEnDevcNsLklSPX0sSgK6QS8LuMRLxmnU5T2m6yttf@yfKoMrAPQH3d3z3LHMP3n7Ff@uD@1e5@7mCjHbdGt0ClyhCaEHSLwFHJKQ/0j7ygTCb27tYEA6N5gVylZkjqKZTojpG5znwuwTieAEn0fgMKg3YDWrMt3PB8zPcVgJNWFYUBVkK1W@ZThkYM77l74opy0K@kFMVQFI6DQCS7fkBnmXmAJPJCjQT4dQc116ASre9vc1EHIMbtUKV16yyaT/Pii9CRDchrnA2ROQaDNJAkkUKCKv7yaDzSalJTIrSK67GUXD1HOiVKBx7L3y3fUKILAHE4jQy0Jj5DL8lN3HngUnWDn59LfJdkk0fkKRCn0SupCj4FiI@dSbAPtBIF18e4hYicMsr7wHR1qHHv7BIllCRH@XrLWtxsDn4AIrf1mSUARxUNnO1M43Wrfg5gjhCEBVxFfs2nrPmpGm3FM6bDNj0hyuY2Qb3LyuDNTzLy7173Q5m4qoVSyQWu3tkOzjZ8AAKwxKaomUVtZBcFCmXW1kkv0R@NlAcNLZzAdmBmAKR0TXMl87Y293bP/j48MnRNVuPFDN@NRrI/fp2qinJ6UYrdMSjxVquknsPlKPH9x4EFbFAuhCRxiD4/ZKoN5VkMYeIIBdnUq4WbRWGV0u3HuPP@an1q/hmtZtQo0TX8FAz75Ev7QuXHtDprquZa6VV1Mrnb0JpAU@JgN7jR3OvoZpInl82Wtv1ph2LX@eEFQ3heUzewkYArqa3takgs18vHBYs/PbpMX4AzYu2xezqtihuZtGUGFoGmDgnC2NrvkckIFLeIBsQkYKsBFHXtr5DrqMvTAJq/Nus3AZZ1MJSBOFC5iaKR0AdB595RSmyMGjq2/IcwiDVMjtCYNmK2/QMTA@G5jy5VapEUvA/i8EzTvgffp1VZjJtAkskUdoRrDS7yTxoAC8pQING7e7JFMZhT5wxN5NOi/33jcD11AHxe3/KJwcM9vF0BPH69Hhq0MILSG4JEgMl4yGqXJcCKeFbB52l0P4q5NdAG6F@weVRL5@YJeWhMeuZA5DtiWQaJNqHqtpioQVRLDRZDLXjItXZohZubIof4YHrKNnfy4zsbIGA3tBl0@4Zs0T8LJ6stCB/9I@ffX4aT4qreInM2fr2XXtX7dqG6BfVmyWJPvFbZ2A0dpW0KJevSwnwuwqY21cLvtFULstDT6Bv7tVQcz@auI/ACWpEoj/SxywxtbltOpnRa6KZsNNktEuqc7uXNkulaEAFDwqQGaXsk4v33wndnrOEUgMmQF/P7uHjtTlmDVWWW@CmTJJsE7@dtgcaF1prTAowBoYkFQJbQxaCYQZgxBuJzBkc0mA4xIUHWfhbEUyfkqL5aQdpQqVm9Tss8i28Zc1RLJcrfoUuS8UyA@67Lg5lBcBek3OBXg/U9c3WAM1g@CsLsYUgvy7xYpRvjCPy0Ld3A@jEIrZqAzM4DGAtLMl2hy7@Evs2tBXQDyqVZ8cP2qWkIrLQbs7ANXu4fsLNrYdDPP8DOdBMlaWo8Sof0X2EydBCYZsb5kFDeQ@owYhXRGosSoarn7Ne8Kaq3sj1fkK/FiBmDjsA/3xhOwCHViWDCa8VYauF/c9@hh/MFhObqnrSdk9T8XymCje1mmd59uFmU5I2G5na3U0dRlGTV7MmjMmVrdz9U2PY7x0MlKYosizLKcrW@Xn8wdYT87lWeDW7zKqlVydjtdCQX81aYqmWPmmxJ0@@eNN@kxRnp/NXYjOh0Yeb9w4vRDWHA/1YpczOdwrZ2EkZv3/KdD1/wmYwbmUn7DVcJ32G/@R@3Yu4dXR3@q/pu1FxkcWaTfzatVgUFaURb8E/DfdfwMUH/o26XJd3Wm/eJBu6PpnNmWmaY6/Xg58zBA1SSx4xyPcOSHqKr7AmPWkARddo1l/MI@h5uNU1PGwq322jDxm7nO0ag8F0X5@b0weTx19@HlzP8Hr9dMWERCuVSkhS46p3pa3nY0zLaH/2k43L9PmT9vaffXOkGBv4OMTHdy4fo/tIzX@4sfHhvXu5XFrTNO5@8uWTX9zd3c3dT@efNPI7OSmzsf2nf7KxoWnbmrLR8jy1FW@cnHwhapmcKP/Zj@LtJ0@@7nn17P/5jTd1FW9FuJ2yIsgJuLJMBSfeS/BTUcd61yv2OgZcrsbm9NeOBf7nG0yt7xT/y/cOX8UmsbqmfO7CcxJ7FSuUYtwJDnjLBm@nsXpsG6MVLmNzpVargbP4X/4tpK9/DHAwZL4Nt3o@gFWYx@pSjZJcxOoFcKiaBvn@39/4RgRDLiZqpMYF113WgEvMFTVxpwXXFl3bAtojlDKKEsSzJ8OJ4TC1dEe9gy8mvMDDNtCwuzFpxvBrwuzwLmNPG6lUqiW3Jbjk5zhHpKiq1lTVOyANpA@3ajVpi3GDi9ls/g4ajU7SjNbAgQ7TuMM@/4e4Yqs8qz83uKdCrLBx98X9eh0Kla1nt@opuvyWRI2qWBId567I0uxFHIYgjdaLR7zlsLqYKWliOp3mzWmGpJJmC07Ci99jsdAHmyy76reUBKL4vrH3jxfbx@vP/7c///6ff4/@vk@//4AGG@2e2Ve2INIpNIk6XHcrlW69LtZd8byJ73Xgo0ylVCkp7ctmYgskUOspUzMfXcTz2fgRfpcaOwDWTFJquCjbup89vtdjC@8696lH/fwAHpk8mF8KcixRjdwh1a7Fg67V39oqNU7rLQkVoprUUAv5lsRT1YOrzBp3oZpErVgWW3Utrx2yu@0Zv9hw02NODEaGhYCOPr71RdnqYcjirR71itWDZPVFnPeNF@IrxBoNpWVQhxD4sbsblY1SpVDRlHZ9/QWsGX2lqIZhPPFip7Hw4pSNLQgaC1nzql9QFeELCziYvU880IwiEmwWXhHnlYtRjWULalsEJtGykjZoixlVxNZG4Ti/D9cG/NE/XOEr3jfIx/emKNevDVZRt7Sskv@wsK@x97sE6CdYt9PpvO52UA3QO3pXVyf6VJ/pc33SmXZmnUl32sUvyS8Vk7lZJ@@UHL/wTJZi2by6GbtDTP2mscGecinUYqngaqZuvZ7Jctt3ksPBnyQ5s5gQ@we46qqmsi3onzJwA6WMnDBmxj9VFVjsHK7Wm63Gmy1ooPXUNknHVl3ysYSH3L7bSkmXlw1wV6v@/3Y9dFbp4i4oXOsyldp@XgfV43m9kQKQz32QssQIqNyut7YpJMzMz80P3m6B8iKlthvbNWePfjI1ECmec@IF524LAG8vIXv3bkoG110AUN@E9phMpTYlaQP7xobfV0DkVj0VlApxSIC2cH7@c/5goAet@HL7sn7Z2L683N6G/226X/pP8L3cvvZPj8W1Js4ivIWipdlQ6k2l6QuLFrzLSh19ZKUJjjo8IV4jq5VaDXTAJbf@2/yX04t76IMot2TAWohtsa0Ymg/MxraE2Iu3X/0v@Gu@/er3UV9k8GdUhNg5NmtlC0ebZT7ohBuzH9vsMb9scOMveEUf9HhcR0@b32xckFKUFzKr8Dn/hFoqJGXsgNtOv40WCWT2AqKi4gZSjolaqSC2U@pcY7FtsVAkIfcL1654PP6PXmjlYpxPz@BB@hee5z2O4LbADiJXtYwqqRd1biuef9bjF1Zd/@gX1l1C7KLMjApQpesxTg8hBuwTUxRJgn6qvj3Crda4QiLhYPS09oX0bFfC2RN9QutfXT4zUDvYr5XLdb64s/mEGsvW/S24q/C/vwHlYM0@xG32a90R6L3NfjavNdGyeEzqvMK/R6/xjx138e/pK/xjx6/x7@kE/9jjDv4dv8K/3Q7@HY/w794r/Hv8Gv@eDfCv@bVsVq2Km@dEmpRaVi83ZyKRqBrbqTe/NnHnFcuwG2av5X80J5srs2Ss@TVjhp9Or3DPfvyn3/3mN@O1WlyK06dIcqrjMjVZBepDibx49W5ciNXYprqpZqxMN6N21A44TJZxWWaYGao9GJ60VZYxWGaembPMyFF74DLgLwMuM9NnmQHL2BkbIkIouCbtzARdfXgM4K8PgFz4M3HnYEfNdBlkZKGqRl8xRPDgumg3hQaLM/GFASNMWZUzcsFs4bdfGuKLF01lq6WVS0xGppLbjRfNeEtsimgPXCvnWGdubDRfiNAdZ0TOfOjDYp4Hw9ZqTGk2FU4moABR8fKy3d7/9H67rWDn03zsHC7@Dw9H0dcb/0eHzuNDZ@TA/@HhITQYo566mwKxfPduDcS0/9iJ1as7zQoJ@0Dgx5TtnWY9K6G7kAIZrqFf6j2vBUR41jeaQvwsgSOOMxx0VD8/q55WyX0WvIKjXV1ECKJxh/@E6ww6tmAQcgbX6Rk66A2dZ583Qxd3KJ@fgdfnDIZb4T8M66Kv/xX@zf@2/h8/Y0mWaLSSifPL7QRdSfxLJs8vzy/9ez2ZSPgviW34Qw94xyTnl3V0UqRzcDUSyVby8pL7wT2R3OYA65DNdp3SLuJBZxALs6Rs@S3xX/cJWftXM15lIIRoSJ3PUDuKiVWmL3bTNJuzTCZZ7QSfOsC1Yf2Ctiwkq/Sdu81OQ2396Y/ocxY7SYqUz1Wr6hbjL1pOq1ZzwVuxVK2WgpfNRKJ8/apndtQCjDpyuWSyWoWXnQBsBl4hbYO9SbEaa8K9decOz6SkXVwEMLO5QiqjZjB1kFMesjU8vesL3PODQ/oSBIiafAw/wcJFSSJD35HBb5XFxYp4507C/wb6zm7yzh2tnLm4CH3GY/BSl7za7Z7pttvon724ENsi7X4p5@E9U7q4UDPllBpPOm7iU/zIHWSVkFT2oVanXMsgxrVcEYJ9BPLb24VcvV7IgU@hFE/iSnoD0W8BvnExXhVj51QGtVTkElCsond0VxC0ZewU2PlljCqU5fLJBAjSJGh@lzH8c1Hm8u4mn08CZS5FHlMtl3nUJMsVEqVU2f@rbcBYHFQb/of6WTaV2ypu3QVNF/@8lWMrlMnVc6OmXtbOjQrOpV9Wu/7ngtGagnHnTrYMJCplqk2h3b6/e7zbbtdEUUT1CG7oSdJdQCMTbrxBJc@XW5wilepdqma1lGdQnzyOFIcegpWA6Iq2lVdLSCTB7KOxFCCJoBKNNtiGoNETb0KZU24DPGEQA5n34GI91mEDvNgAp0SZySy6mMV4ON273TCSwy8/NHyltHiFPkZ4CX4rzHIWhU78yaPdvf3jtLYtsZj2YHcvrR09uxdT8TW/eKfgLL4/3d@9f/gMEjx5tL97tP/RwWf7z56Av8fOFlcg9P374hl1rXg/Y58LL93XumHoxtQw2mfT6dkr9tI02yZUpjWFQjkDl3lGG8oy1hflqsKva3r6y5e6O6aLvf3ht9/@8L97@zvfffs73377O9//6Vff/zb8fgy/7/Lnd/9NOY/3n371z3737W//Dnj@B/j9Efx@8tOvfuMb/Efvfwy//xTx@2P/F4nHfwLA@pWffvW9H/30q1/9Afz@pf/7wfXfr/1k9e/731r/w3Tf@92b43z338Lv9zisIO53f5v74fNa/N/m8X71B2//xb/j/3/q/6Hzd97@iz/Gm//yT3/wp//p7Tf/vaaV/vRfv/3W995@65tvv/Wdt9/6x9rb3/jXaiZ6@9233/@Dv/rD3/urP/wf6f/HdP@9d/l/@4N/@hf/61/873/xh/7vJ/D7d@D6yV/8e2gqf/sHP8T/7/3B3/7RD/H/f/5Xf/sHv/63v/I/keM3ueP/@Zf/ht//@tf@49/81nf@6iff@Jtf/8nf/OYf/NX/8av/12/8x7/@73//r//JN9HzN3/yV3/0K3/5zW//5bf@@V9@86s192/feP/qHfy/@gfweXc83wXOu5TrfX2@@rnw@ftQY5EL8Alw9y@//Y1fAgb/F4y9/faP8RwS/Nb8/1hTKc6P@dv/Bxza9TJjSAZc8Pv1t9/@LpLofwASwX9Ir@@EL0sh/OU7ixcg62@tSPTLP/3qn/@I3mJGpU5rNdh3l7RSagvGN1vlst9/@8s4kOSXlqGFAPycvoMSainsOyjb3v7wG29/9I/f/vA33/7wV7DzlnLl9G5aUm9ZA4OI@XeIhxEL7xIPI36B@adoYk1KfQFv7As/8IsvvhDaFwoeeLt7Ab5fkBe/GA/CA3F@UBCG/nhCjl2wqNt3Znznpu8b5sxY48WLFq6ygh/mniLdYytQjfJZNksF89RsFsxXY6TZFp/IxTv5YvBMwNvif@GcCSy1mOHGD/QFTnL46fwsuFPIQzap2SwyUU56D2HIfWh1mPLNlRmWYDZLzWAQDA7IIQVB90Adr9VSmLDG8YFXjlq9xAiVVKoG5cbUPE26XUIQs3sEBVLWUk9Ze6s24wlTCK8ekCMloNdTUdXEVKl2HzKsze4zhIXACeyLF7V6qTarI7g3nB6pWeoe4YTAaqlZ/Q281wgmpBNi998AKqVaKlUvYYZYSF496TavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCJm/x37jL2oaiWxDZXGJFgPDbeU4vYGBGiQ3gzteUXh/4DJ/22iOAblJWfC@PhO6Sb7nB1FSMAXEmSZZnBD5fdd9hdCJ5xUCnKFh4pDiFFHEEcEHownB9KCSmq3xS9QP6x2tZ7XwgMC7O5uSnE6mJWPJSJdIrC3JMKnXjATYA4vKgwsVAW0dug4x8BLpC@SvlvxnE5Lc44YPZhiv/u3t1iH0Ix6bnwE5iUyjo5J8ahbKdSogbw605KeA7DEgH4lABdCPKsRst3KSGdZkyuxTCMHR4e@kiQx/OakAI217IqvuMi0nQ6jUEKWU7L6bT/lOlJHrLvkCnUf8qbSFz6CjTTtFwVRk9Vhl4sOtRRYQiMnm/evIFaoV1VlQMYfDJ/g5WWK1EgeHC7H5Y1D44JabmywEfmTC3kGEvQFCtcSZYUWIJtJQW@F58jEVyJuFYqxSkeUF9ObAX77QoqsQNOr8bqiGhw8SFhKZ8MAvcO2d7h48f7nx6PWy0mGPRVa6M9dp2u4XkJDNv99D4/h6GVC8lYo4GgjysaChhhv5IhYXxw/@nBUYXxQvtVkCDEqrSa6hezrAqx8fjz7Zi/30jED7M54hHeK4uyJbRyFpLG6kKsa@DIApfJq7TPpCo89gb3nBmM6dOimFYLOLJL0qQyE37RmTI0G8ptjECbwtMZ8vY2UUCon0u0YIFOqK2CUK/7O/WYKtSP9o8hwfEhU7WMLNS/YDMZM5QuhbpVswx7MBlu4pY3sZkRI2XabGTS@Kdls3BXc4W0mi@2NjascwnzbFK1nePexUt4PZewGB/AxYQPBPYBeMEFeeCGRObvBj04rPpb8tBAV4LvyxPVPDSzpIDz2BycMI5eVeDu5eUfIbbx5ZcTVq/D@Fo6eCDEQFoMWbArTTJ78lCmau5NXYNCB4z1zM9M/OKe3DO9saXPoekANWKXl5d9gHTwgGl1jV55ih7eL7vk0wH35UwXYnalUnuj5oqCdlKpvMlqmgAewpaC2942gAFo98CWwv@qHmSSzZYUkFSqKMIjm80KOHcsCBVDYLRF5E2mVpM4D2ZzKu0QEfAjDvqspoWXH3f24SJuNsPjYggEsMHEZZkgrMjD/LeCQG9ANNwTR58MrvqNM3PnThYnMbK5TDhbQSVml1A3m9lcFiku/P8XHrviqznb43o2o24rY3Dq4MxtKzo4O@DMbysdcJrgLG8rJjin9aya2VamdYEJ29xEJ0MLIDVxYszQIjD3E@ueYfVlPFFUEykDTdz2TV7Xg4T1Xq3ndOl739WebOJ31/G8Lk@Qy4lVx0bjcTU0I0EnnFkieS4Mamd0qlgwagMZ7ZG4tm4JPbnj9OayN5lbeDbHctxaHNTBeBCwgG6AHoJzXzvZbK7SYC157Ix3BC1fTDXUDHQg@FNLaS29YewUi5We3LUM3d3JV/KldA@P/fhLXDv5TGUgf/H40cPJZPzUoLNAO7kyJEALXmhrZ6dUyedbjYYophqUTQu/VszFk7SxAW3a0HsSPHEBzJO0UgsS90y3VovHd7KqJqmVbKZ0KSwIhzTHEtYFTJrCkqWR7ue@BKjYjg3CppLW0@Y5UaHS7/cvt85TixdBP5f4G9DnUtLTnfPwtSpF4lXYNC2Zi0Dw0ftA7nN/ba8iavmSWG1UF@/FglhtXQp3R0bP1PEIUDNzfj1VAYQyhxqDjJpMuKy4jjOpdIy@4xqLiFm1EETkCF2PkBMvw@yaGczx/Hp2hUik2fl1KLm8eBmmCtASLi@B7pzYQHbf/mqdtso21HKutQ8iCNhnOzDNitFiz58Lsa2nn2Xrdajq81xRy@VzeS1bKOSLGvQ35VwhX4LGlilk8poGUHLlUrl4CXytKG9i9OU1tnce8HuFbM8n9Ao3nthoseSbT03rvJSVOB6JZPXyMvZGiH349DMNOsi1VwI63c80qV7L5svgyqJLywLCTNA0SctKWVVSs/h/i0PD/3ePr8G/hndIldWEY7So8il0m9DV2@wRWmaYOOzYwW/zDNg9o7smxt5Qp33Me67jeX@POPd0@4QH3Te5GdMw6KGOHyjzRuZkuCbGs/EIjbEY7j8YhP1RBxBEccgj3IObaznOqghF9uzJmlI@Dg2HAzG45XCI/vTgo4fHkefx/u7eQ6HA7h1@ev/KI@9HyrNH@w@Ow9ciDw2S5kMQv7j/6NHVV/@RO3z2tD91XPwJDw6f5Ra30AuPyQo5uJYjhd4ExL/hKymWoFHAQCxfDByqgIcr7sDg@I7vzBcWzgw6P@dngE0v3OzPj4NXhOPgYLDOUNJ2DNblNndwtE728HxdXi2WBWHMbOeMFTOs51iWjl9b72@A51DHQ44GKrSWhZyIWZ85rtU7M3vGhvAYz1OWVfyyNSIhPAQgo2mXbCmAMoPWVXv4HXRclupYU4NNx2ytJzzQC52uORhCH3zmBBGEjq4z@L3vBemN6DW52WPC8yC/ayHW9ehCTBDFPVF8qE/0WaxU9TKVyp076hNXLGfFMVDSGxj7M2BZ9gyakO7O0yVxIosPmNoe4LKG5YxjOgxBGqCwl7VGayen1UuZfPavf@vHf/cnvz6oqVvNzF5me@fxIxjZ5Csg2kCLZaSo@sqsTMMarVzKl8pZrZQulUu5vFrI59OqloYRYbEMg4KMWlILpXxZTZdyZdBCcmUIzZeLviqsBLqvslUBsHYXv7S8TSMjeQhDIL4MyV4n9CSL6eH7lIkGpBEFHIRO6MD4llmDDpSpGZYtMoCosy6LPXiwl3nwQBTv4Qtu49jLiGIPX/KlTKZ4TxQNCtkroUYlOjxNCW3WiRP@ksncAypPOQA09y6KQ3zZL@B0miia@LK3@@AB5tPHFw3TQ7QTHsJfrOClCNFsfAENnQC8CqFBtF2eT44Q3ccXzBJDHvCQPQgTxY8CdDDkKY/GATwMSrq7K4oH/GV3F0P2qNh5jugn@LJLlyi68AKsL4oDcAxcaHSi2AEnNgBR7IKrO9fBD79qjRbB7YkuinNOHiSQKM4ott49EcV24I/ZfOZjk0fqVuhF5aW@Sy9l/BNFLUAao2XDl6wo5sKXHJTt4cPP9OGkZwz4NXf5swslffgwq5uz6f6DzkcfdQaDjjvf3f/oKQbt7T0EbWQ@dTuDjp@w04bLgVR7DzX9ZDS/ekGpD9rtim6tDPqk3c7p9pWg9rxtIIaQ6hVg5l8DzGjU3oOgvYftu/qqZWQC2Ma2P4JnB697I3je0zs8KLgoiJ6zTkesIvsrSjMh4HgBF4CxOZ6ALLXTI73rOlV8n9VYJo0qy7xRyLSqFMBGoPdnqpcY3k/gXce5n@T5vDGrZVq1Wa2o8X1I/YTYnGl5U0xvjHbUcr6yoe@oWi41q6DNCqcfZ3FJ3WEJ9c7Wa5b4NLmjwRhAbO7sSGJDbe1oaqlSKD7fmopisoL3nWyxAhEz8QxjeEs2iq2dYj6SpFhM6YpWKRZBFQOiTKBH7@CcTDuRODP0k2QS0cUZAigClZXNqZxmtZ@YpWc1jhebJ6uzmlrllnBZ5hqsHppdn3YnjsshDgDcbCdTwRX4hKiWSyLkryiJZDIUejBeFxYbPz//@vHJ8fEXpPLV/bmLJ/w78VX/9aOHe/LBYfCGBtPlB6iJOq68h1JrKYSrpIHXMYxB5IfQicJ4LvDDs4GuY8n7tHMO1NkgIDABJPvGS@Xjh0twjobOGc8ZTStUyQKe3TUY2pM3e0yv1cGl91iCsGJ68oy673a9XmvXRmR9AIoYpPqEkbH1BZgDj@MeGnyg5Od4Xs4PaNcyl9VObRabAZx2jUnqi5HTe6GlutUempG/V7uHiatteHaqRs1wXccVYTQtVvs7dm1qe3rfeGK4aMrk4HATlAk8RJfoMyO5yZr7GHsPRyqXUt1l9gKzT6ejhC7VO8llr8grkibx9aDI53SqE3doXFb7NZZ4nqy@gld3kyV68r3kTq7aS9xj7ST4ZF70X/SZxgq5Ko0yEggJmhHRBsusJ2v1T0D/4YBPKhVAxK/jE4CJOQFYs0cBenJsXla7NYslJDZjSSJPrjqoNTD1Bd62JVFsSVLjoiXUJelzoQ4ttTqP6TVv2qFvj7BMR9UyheoM/NRirjqEitWfz6pubTx1jaoFr/5EHj@8qleBnEA1APP6IvH2l76R3JbyNe5XJVAXFqgcbbldm1VttGYILFHL1iAg1chl0jB6h1sxDb29VkirhXQ2nUtLRfSFrj6dT4MnjG5AuUhYCZExMZ2ZZWQ1rRpqOpF5YfZeJNMnCdBZiGQsmZ44@/Z0xMAHKgm5kl7hqbNkStuyYNTVc5i@LRGbgqyoYsGA5kM2NtNDBPXU0C1KkUxKLLuVsDYTGGfzeDreb7Qqlf3Z@OsQlJBe7RRSxUzqdTJZTWwka57xSqhXhTrKFSr1eAN41p/jZN501IA6Bpda1CqNRgeLWMyks5kslM5sXwy2xbrYSmc2CipU0SUjgcG4xIhO@6Gus/Abt1HrtgyoOrWsVQWZ5uCyJU0qK/mtfIbPA/KUwtgXbEhJlmiKwUHtRDxe1OLxZLyKKxAboj/lDNKMJFkcxGr8jrojghomVsSyhhEWQpHO4mYC7EARuxRw4oPlYFB7LlyeX27Xha8JR3jCclt7jn/F5493D/Hva@BVhtfS88fPDp8dPhCYQps85XasulGVq@0qvEhy/a4QqzAGMrTpW5FSNhh73@2jqe36c/5s4mkBgCuQheIGa9G2LsPEERv7DC0U7LA4lEF3Rw1Ny7YaWhF6PZCjQVRNU6u4PhPD8whyHSrDOwf8tlN1PNz3CZvP9ZQUDPPvMDZIbQpEntjVOYDd2u7g6W6wM213b/VMweZMwcnpJujquJMtdh6PxS/hT4jdpaOGGj9qyGLhYUNcU/WXQ7K5AkuWg9WKr8XvxuLxOC4LVJj3Jkb1Fhze@uSFBiwTs53AA0ZLOJMFnVk@j3PnMeXF2PtSK2UfHxza990HBj8ZpJVydDIoo0p4JKpa8X3zYnvjRAWOyYrZk3SM3Y3RxnqxXNJEjXtUY@xEiquVdBoqublxseHgqggL9@q9sT/@OmPjeDYXZ6xZi81qOX8TuFqvS@q2hqbZiqwCsr@vFqTMRZ3zeJ0CChqEvP2lH@Rm2yV41zIqvGtaPqXV6@qWxpKx8duvfh@t7Jzvf7b7iMVxLv3v/uRHWvHv/uRf0Xaz@CXNr2vZYgxiolMtFGPn5@Pz80u4eFg@1opxpHLFJLj5Wo8aqyuqlrVtu8oqiq5vFVM57a5dVfy4alFNxjwp5q9aFfMx78IP0jIlCAqWlchLLGANxPafmnlNvbu9A8XZyea06gbUvxoeNWXh37bhlaF2S49fXDAGL916bzAwNXIpCqu8kdj2G2mbvcElnTfSBntRq@PWABUPqAZLHlt4YA@X/eL1lLIVZzA0YvXGZfWylaI1ExhCPjeMLbt5hWGbG3hiY9lry4Y/Y8ujP0wUeHjwGrwZWy89MbGVVJReLzTltm2wfB24YksB3LaCdQ/@J0nN5Ntf@g1NK/zdn/zaRfui/YUGg8lyuaBqsZ/9bHtqTz2jV/8ZJLzBfEowIKRFI7Rzgo5wIMm4PUPTTxU65C6MYac2Ks08fjCsxIEkA4XDHNhGj4aVwikqSVSRbW7Br5egaFtoXSFNSjdZzEpWBSFUTkmpdgfdNMFgW2iEs9FKCufCBxgEPTEDxbwqfLAABR4j6Hudbtuzpu6YzrckKJ3aSrM7kARy@ACNI26QVQhfjEsgz5St60k5yh5RjRQqNjI8D00tQg8kfABJfEvF1pyNdTRggjFNG/oNGaMQnhTQa0DeLcjb4gna5Jug0vMIacax44lsULyFD0CTICqYoGAwcxsiVEEKfQAEgDIkfMBmi22zbJKdm6lUdWHH8RL35KNhSj0wniBgMoTWQ2MdQeIqxgMvUPjx25jIF34Ng24X8QyAcBh8Cb8GQwZMTm@osZF1k3cGBbDIkliCisbu3FlgVauZvSSjEiH8E3OME15UD/ZqXAFYMNz6sFcR0wwtZFYD35DtgOIpQhe4TuKmMauRpEzE10tBgP93ZlrkyCtVRQFVLIBfX7xVdIFkkBjJzuuwy7ZrTNWKSRYi3wXcu4QUnWEPx5DN2Yey9kUQeAkY/iwWfHkGRNRxdBLR59ur1jMYaNlT/OwH2lDjwsC3esGtpKGoO5gEqcNUUBTToth904XRDe0tCAw0JrJqEpMtDFoSHrRrXssx3LyeT@KDUmFsBk8dDQ36@WyQgaSuAxXqjR2bLBOS5SQ8OQAcATLKN@rG0Z7aZ/iZKL9uKHEUI48MuiHnI8ZkaZG@r01pcXG/48IgOKBNmhkDmXVHPaaVWYIYjYzP2SG4JCUihDugKiONO5YxApSODIOOm3kVRRmA@jTtkAW@xybw1fCBCf2N7Sn@p8yVM/PEVI7xMxeS08dTadyeSQw1Lmx@fB@Bb@3OcpwTZpknBp8bTixZg/EYDBZA300DZRc/IGwFN6ho2TTOVqhpHgt@RXgUubOUjqTdSMyT159ZdSPRxhq9oM7HdPEz5ae6HaEvXReCPz725l5gT4qsIsG7HIpcw7ckU4ujjYjQRJLgW8aqkVEmGdccxgkxJgYWpdApjF3jlOFIV8A@BoRmN7DNgq0YSvsBdQDU9qBloaHJiVtBi0KAidtLdKHp@QLeZh@yrCZgRG7uyzfNBTCw6mvL0CEMkmI5vEkPKkamiXaUK9A6Rz0IQ1sWPvth@oC70U1GQBfszTZ8cNjpUF41xptF8JKPvGDrQH6mom9AYAEwXIHJRkJMAdiUmBQ56DD91eSc2wWSJRV2HVKaIQSf1ACFVAUdRQ59VX7xPScBAu7pHjf675uhPDs7k8k26tQ1ZcPDbxx5jq1bynhgggLtKBNjNPa/JmviV8R9uAuXxD9tJo@H450Zqq618p05fwpC36v523wS8b4Xx87xFD/hMxiRHTU0YOYRQz0w6fNf3YS/64jzn9ZKnwf8V0H@k0rxSwTCGIKZpefpbhqApTvdk3T/rFf1A06pQQJwqEUj8ESLxW7wMvIClznuhzGcCcrRMKhjndDKLUAS@bTuImtewiDmPHj138fmDBLZxhnbdV19nqDwJMZGBk7MSe1hc@j2KQSc0M2wc24@15w15q2l5LMwOXRq4b4FF42kCec3A@W2lDF8xsNnED7j4bNFpkG2jVmLq2TodYnFQa5H25pBTAQzD@JccrvDixCCDNo3UzkIjDlf8ruEX7dGqQN68zeox1rAGMATYyC4kVAaz5uNZsv2jLOtVkoZALOLRAiocQDdaBFNz3qhG6lvnVpjx1vystGkKvRKPt7o1R363MB5BcsYVhAxBqeXiVYwByN/gwVXCPwCAwTUwyAQVYPdScJMVkPb3RQIjNMQFzTmiDV8ZFqkfflBvh@oS5z0nLBRQK0IIPQPiwRoQggLWg7/ol0gHT53HYgTxJXoI1wjtMYWb8WBkleaCpc1VaqkCFaSFKAJZEd1tXa1KEE4VEXjSlCkmJd@/UfR33hv9PvQLlZjTwzLO4yqEG0quKcRVAi/uRBVWb0WqVfAQNnSLcOFnmuf66d@bw3ZbCnBMIPng0XwzsxJd5iIVH43yeuHTk6KtlgJWWFeq0ER5zXeLHm7CEjKCR4m8/xk84AR/PRcgACMzMpkhp9sFk02q9W44GCzNcnOIkjOCMkZT8Jjz9Yg2fKTwejpIOhesHpaoJ3ipksR4Km8GwU1aCwyTz81cBn8JVqKxKUEP8@FzCEu8HkIVWzks25rZe6NCNIRoXUFADLiNQA9/nHcinBV4KlS@BbKKE7KQEbxN58NuKwABiMRXOXWlBMhk9EYGBR@MUX9ALRdMdUQRJUmhfEvw39iOvAMfup1z8xyTHXZM5O@8vcP4tlCykYaaET7UDM5FMg4knlm@2ZIozpHDL8jP3RAq@ucOSyxQtkGf2XqJ1U6ltNRRjpuZ8FPZnJfeTxPBuMHXFBhd8fORJ84uVyFD5pMYrtV@fMxgzmwHfzSTsSiOuh6Pcfw7PgEKrXrDGzTM9IMjV2eGP6ww/C/CCFE9WTf6XiC4G@s4sNYBM35ClXddhs/4t1uJ3C/YrISbr6m7YvInvG4gONfcEXSg3jygR6OE07npdGdJG@HiZ8H8JMdm92TxOHYD8RZ0l0GMqwL@j@EDkGDYZ6zGDmS6XFUpTuTBH1eY@iMnAFofVNPFjD1FfAHC9iIkD4eEy5ppuOQthL5SAS1kkQ3rSf9pJ@8d1L2iZbQk2F6bRnAEjHSzL1KY6SsuyK79trseLIgv6P3x/coiu/RzfjSKPwqznxoXuOB75d1NrGAABEXaGRvRwOLDnKrdw2dJVRCb9SreIJ3RrFH28V6iOkuRN31o8t94I90@ObBW4j4Z@vof3MFBsn337X6dGj27GgO8maEOy8T9HE0L1gZTUD0gyTKnuvZhax9/x3zgrj4XcoHqEKAGkuCy0arydAwxzDs9sLp4gDwLTyPO7Su8T1t26rxwBU4uadpdqKtr6L77Z5h6XOjl/BjpiNwgxI/hQEbyat3KzgKOhJ6Dh/rJaDvSoah0I0j0XmkyhqW0dOnyeR6tuJRzJB7aKacMDxYTz8MvyaacYqvxmerYRwQj8dwOvbUxOnP8Xw854b5Lf5lLF@O8v6H1yRaf7idIEAH3nuq6UW2yZvE59NEWKR36BHCuPJykdFudgARjSpdr8P3I9HtJYXKjSSqBbUsLH@SZnWNmzfVeIQrAp7kq0zvxpK3Md0781yE1TiwhQjbe78u5Bpk3MzR7SaiELnPjTXm2NdkAvrRPJ29pldprxCoYUqSdBOThtukXyQFHBkfwBMnnD6DJwIcGJM2Z6igbDin5X9sklHISB9HtBbfB5R0gBKhIie5j0YklhC4Ifr5ZZhnd22e3Wt5dpfyDFvAcpaRSEJ3KUu/FrB6bqoCy@hP1khnDMKxMzxuEttw2Y7u4mzFedyMV8w0i5/GKyCQ40a8sp8AoRzvxSv3yeHFK0fkOIlXPgHHom3FL@KVoFlgBBdeyXEX/X0Rju/deGUvkbwUJvqJ4QX5yvFKWKcQZ4e/EkWAFFhu0Bpxic12/GJOXAM6NlIq0ww5xkvj8InmYdL0y8A//8gUfX4GA3GOc4sisxRTlzqNSI/B84FuI/i8wYqWXPF78/3DB7QZKoyC2aRgjBdNQ@BBDY/Fl4URRwxDaUUDnoAgys3KaoxYpCd7R3T83IFDqZKX8yfqyaQP9BIU3oDIrUUm9GUxP31QX8sgeAW@G56YeB2e19AJsiOMcE02uQItJOqL@A2FwrpexsWv/WgN0Vz3ciTAVgqi8FoisBGZDjocLc5hZmNnvMwkFIqb7s1oGpqU440SufdKMpIKfstcE0zefslQMEQbf/Km4kTSIWpLIggDG5kWb2Vhv0CyGIMWsi6iqfLGByhEZA60cKN7Ql9tu@87KR4XN2nqK9Z1Q0FaniVJrmUxCYlltGY11f/f7r51q41kSfc3eoq0hBuVKZUkbDBGCFuAsLU3Bg8Xu30AqwupBGrr1ipxkS@9ZubHeYEz/@cRzqvMO8yv8xT7xBeRWZUlCWx373P2rOm12pSqMiMjIyMjIzPjMpLWo81rFTGufmz7amre4qwlCwBWzagVka/9H9Df@6K/G4XaEGGigVmK9eyldFq9vneVncC8Ezc7PYD46KptZ6ZyFLUQk5x2B5Zmfh@vTan4MPkQJV8ajaBPaPuGbNGe4Bt0m9xbCCxoCcPr5MuPS/Ty49LdhJrWSDrXnlFaPLSk4UjHI0zjrt2Pq3R81hDjC59v@50fHuBhcoDtwQM87sBwguQyy4dXPbZyiec2iW15A5FaXFMiyPm6NBrm@CWJe766ja5t6cV@/WB7f2/3PS26T58@dfQaPY7xw6zFWWu0jgtktqyO1oMZ25YlF6mVcNmN4/jwsj8cPTjtpadkiQhrUgZ8asWwn57jjpZlljyfmLtUT8paFNWwPsbTwE9IJag6PpbstqbriAgSjLKPfA3EqLdEb5d3aw4nEarXe343qNd5@TKJcvUqhqExN@LO3zIP8lfhkBPCSgasm1SKw0qo7X317lXlSB29qqqd462/qvf7x@pdZe8IEQXeHG/u1rYU/V/dO6yqVMKOEtkCsaEkum4HjQApYNVSofBEMeSt/mAscie75cj7Q7@rXvUbAa6p1kO/@@JSfni9YLQhtaq0HR3jDLPN2SG77RHsLTidIW1jodw02VEQrgCKyp7TnraLPW@332y32lQ2hb3voB2ExrdMddo0giRvjXu1K0oSMhey6RBnJIUF1g1V96k87m4IjC/2VyAxSkiqw6anNOGi/36YgkfVg9eHCsEptvb3tmtHtf29Q7Wzf0A/37yv7b0ketYOjw5qm8f4xAVf72/XdmpbFX4hCBQ8hagRv16Fo3tR8FCcqdL4iJtvb0DDH/1KnnpDg1c3PrtMhmrhqgfp0/Y77U9Bc6GUugqhvsBNk68KVHa@cvDyLa35KvgNN5zmKpjtD9LHIWfTnC@odW6NJssGzbeSnq607OWKDt9HdMcKCXWCEkeTyPKzqwxwNuJptgOV3oKNCs6@JegEz2UDmhp6QLAByhislBUnwlpYcNcZ5Aa11uj0ESFUWhMjQv0DVV8YU5NSiimmbWUAFM4OtR7Og4ql6AXxPb1Y0s2OhlJAPY5eSAH1RF5AFa3BdkQt6xJXo/0riGe1Ii9@7Q52@FpYPY1ebPq8i13VOMm48ZD6KkokiBAcHU53Jqc8nJKVs2hzlZDLIxVYpyMTI5AklCQT5SqRbduoZJqETQtXDdrsTXI74ytxA@yE/NYoVNmy46kjGAcFvbYkmrvo@D0xgYpNd5j31CqiHZW1R3Y7StDG7iODPjMgkkMm8YjqbWutMPjeelRzc6pFX9tIcpJUY4L2LQQ2pxD4I2AIUC6x02nwSsVerADTb2lWzoZ94kic2/5ulyd2bl41gkQFbbWV/bX96ZOjiewm9knGTpGxoyH6FAxJreSrzFZ/SHOcxSqntIIUbFz2B6O2jGE22QO@ceJljkpjYaPWfilvJFoDHSZb7PV7VqPnxMV3tHpOTPk9rTLHy915JL7iXMfE@bQIi90d0PHP@9eBdXfm4hLpJsDxCynCfFeOw8/xiDER/TMVy47fFVKkrpY3tjdPc7//4iJPqogFSVNsjA7xPzEm2qLpwfd8bLA4hN6lZ5rJbxdenaO2tsHT0hKz3ACjfeBlm/Z1L@ql6JuYG0@/h4PN5Ht@@eVLWWrlIJl0buvwMhtLN1edmCZdrnOmtAmIJTsJWZL1WfPGZZiRvH4BpxqMAsL39CBHsG@fyB6nRYjp3flViySLTuKrhzuC76gNtqiIM6DDWcYej/yH7GZ5ccPJxwYlyiJn1oho10AuOo5llsLr1RS47fvBkfz@fnCr92Iny8MPQdu@F9oP4ZZbvBuWLEsWrO8H@/s9YGVx@0Ngqe/u3YBlkZyGFnF6xJzufCaypr2/xV@mxo7nHoHB2osTlAio1dpVj6@oTbztrFRwbDCxQnR4tF09OFBp2Z9QXZJ72DI0tRgE7AfqTWxt2@6xsPMipSnaLEfKk3mTsGiL3JfumcwziXeHqNA6iKvpEQmLOKp3q30rUk@vLKxCsPU9C0RDuSR2n40MCk804K@0ByRk40GzOpia2c2MLD7t0DYC13RzRTe2bfjZwlrWbqTGHY5tQLZNkH8Bz5LZ4/dO9OM1044oWIh5hA43SZOm9Yb2CYfU8IAKel5yBO8ZFjOkMLIXBTtjaAfDr0JSw/7zDMWMJEq46MKWWNfKsUZN9ON5o@awQSKWAR@WnvqjWDTTByPi@c26PaBOvOhlk0sQKZlIlvrC5gqqfvZVL2FMjWidLEcKuT3X5hmbE4PlGU5nNezS3YUewhZ6ZVI8TDZF0vbepnJ/n6ZklUi0ZGg@szPmI0FeWV5@/C3Yk70w1XN/FrasIZPyc9Qd0P4@BhmOQz7eJ86t7bnme8wA95BOTOvNhJmoSKrOjDUl0XdejGz8CBc5FyJkEKQe@WcnW3XU7QRus6HLimRD5yJTfbCmcNRRmTVT1P96f3MQyN9s78GPtyeTDYVgOvgVVvmv@8MwiL3yrPgu1is4xyffBcNhj4uJP1MXULLsxnSvsx1724nBq/QKH/m@ze5JS3snidmta84auBE@XvSQchqne6XJ471csWR3dae2W1WPOGhlK3EWmR6mHUv2PGj37kOAZTCfS2D5YB@@h@Ea/U84uAYkkYm9@bJMG@ebuDFFSGs@4SxG2ixUy9bi5Oi3wobfQ0QQN/0wVGn3J6rIp7DV/R1n1sl6oZSoT8iFg16WarnpnJfmqvQOB7qAlAQho4n31oIFTw1jKQn3mos@7KNwsRXcyukZW076@eJqYeVZinvXc0du9@TZmfuoUU4rWnz9Xje8Gt40P170L69bqqMGv57fNsafflNq@Yl6TG0t/SSRg4sr5TwHa31K/66qZwXmXI3gc46CjBTInuSGVWpBxfvw0gPl8ANvmtfgITHBpepR13AhXOxG5e7Jylm5Vy6Uuie9sxKc/EaL5dFicTGLFz/RKkoyRm7mT0ZnWFPtU9egd60Qn5NzkGrXEMWuIfTmtT9s93crey8Tp3FQAHAEpm29@UBd0k3PwZoNvideL7jJ6mMyV4FjU1CQUnPsFVSE8zufJ@M4ptkmzGhUXNJmw1v@d@yk5gre1WDU5y8mGiNYS31pf0nNGTemAp8oUJGTtonZCP8CghOXyeJiSN6OxYo6VxR1rQjfSccCcYKaLA7Tp@k0fAqBqPblOjlLhV7gNy6BBPKrf@Fqan2ds60Tq4Uen@LBlMMfssNE4QyPuAChPwO@bUATrLmH7PaRou7jdxEP8obPqEbsJ8MG8inWFPEF5t/qM/s3cf11IoAQfk50Lk8fcWrNixRJ8R3kwwWEOktu/HHNALdKGZQ5dBawpb1yDJwtxZlGaFaTid7P3YCcQiv6T/cgV@RfU92IyjtSnEnC99T6Vwha8pDypw386cTVsla1nKlmClukmPsmNXDSRduj1wFNq7HaCjodQlpoMReTA4/s36vbX4zaD0/Q5lmEvHzPTX3PJb578l2Qikt5tMDHhdbsQunM57jcV5WOi7lTbZUVKy8ejXTDI5UkLlu6r2zojfr1dlx4IxpK4crow3riQ8768mHG6MuXB4k6EYNH30/ku@bvJT3yEZaJsi@S7eNvSg9QwMaz2tZkgku9XrvzPKVTc@svYLM0UVMpqc7JF5WZVGXtg6nFCWlwOOfnabtRjqEsFo3E4TmT3lh/kfa0kvE8O4mGeDFOTawZc8SiEre5yIS7ZYdFaoc/P7BAMEwwmjIzd8NUHuvKYwssSj0wzYoX5NQEp65NTvEy/CK/4B8z2ZPImXKZ2R/nBPNb6bx4NycJxEL3QXo2mZLSBO4i8lJ36p5VJG57PAlxtpDYs06BozYD8cFu4Rj8QSQnbEFhJMUU3aMvmtJxgaJh37uGEB@/pv6Wf5R66ZOOPegEt6qCbYbPXliphIP7KAhHIQJDcdCa8Gow6ODWkRW@G3ah1mFFlpZx3RJDtFZ2L1WDZY@Ud/GkHdKpkqf2AfkGBiLxh/Dq4gLOZPCA7d9AtOLEpT3yUpXeWA40aM48XhI380Ah@AYL4E77wkZCRk5mDygdDvxG4KVIRwtJ@0lJV1ttnbKUz9PhN4LQY7SkraVS/3TVbnzceon73KfFwuOiRbJrfR1c8B4/iR2siEjmwxKiBy4Xn6RS1t1wQ@6GcwDoql0s9G@JN4ProNcLUhVaMbhgSEprGAyvg6aXSh0E0SUw4IKVcTMJP@z@1bAhhzukdPnEjPASDl25DiMOw1@sz3Jd3OC7MjeFS6v4tpmG@rrdBAGNx0mrj9thvrBAmAChByp1gxER5ZGjkijx3bPGhXWXLg6iiBqIc2LdTURk6PVH7QaNDJ9kpToESq5B4sZ6zQlMqL1Gx4dzsDcLAbjHxBQwCJirpPtwSOlL8x/CQemOmTt234xMnqRfn@cKTfdg2CbpGxOYR4WrWbjTAB@9qh2qw/2do3eVg6qi5zcH@29r29Vttfme77hxUc5xeNWr/V2SLtFtutya79OLdOWQaqb5Q6qy915Vf35zUD08VPsHqvb6zW6NoBH4g8reUa166Kra3tbu8TbfvhMEtbd/pHZrr2tHVOxo3@VWTbVUXE/t76jX1YOtV/SzslnbrR295xZ3akd7aAy3@hX1pnJwVNs63q0cqDfHB2/2D6sKHUtt1w63diu119Vtj9qnNlX1bXXvSB2@quzuTnR0/91e9UCxkYDVy80qYVnZpC0sWuJ@btcOqltH6FD8tEXEIwR3XXX4prpVw0P15yp1p3Lw3tVAD6v/dEyF6KParryuvKTOpbLfoAqNy9bxQRXRkkCJw@PNw6Pa0fFRVb3c399mWh9WD97WtqqHJZXa3T9kgh0fVl2FhIrcNMEgatF3et48Pqwx3Wp7R7RmHL@BvYNDg/yOCENYVqjqNhMYZhDoLRFp/@A9oIIOPACueveqSu8PQFOmVgVUgEXF1pFdjBokIh7Z3VR71Ze7tZfVva0qPu8DzLvaYdWhAasdokANBhnviXWo0WPuNcaJ8JJHYtaU4VyXh1PVdlRl@20NmOvSxAGHNc0tTLatV5rmHuL0Woco7T7ODPyufbDSmn51HSAy5fSJzOwzmihi0tb@dpVWZB3aKh1/OKZVZ3UilJL9jVaa6CP9TISsaQbnVxf1dq/Vh49pVE0OPrrhhYs0QQ5yrJym7smWpc9XuEImU6@/rdRpo3tYrzvu99RMoPGtGvoY/L5Sju4jcjBg542Dn7U1oft6glAbP@mLTjbUwwUESgr1fxLTN78bOCqfbwa6Gpz3AdgcHYVybXKJqxQSjezsiOQwcZN8MsG/25oduGLWgPcadZyTwjKSC/VD@qf3Jf4hi4P1gqSzHHfl89jEMhrtT4FpRhrhkAj8j45I0G5xk14YBB8vsgW7Oez5vYt@v5l1HFOHy45oH3iRdb5R/Ty4mKiem6zPyPK1s05fEJp9N6sw0f2zJpnS4@INuWdZ/FMf8R/HYCMxH3Bqyk3xYbU@tMz@JNVhkeQqHdoC7hU8yND5Xld@rr3Dbq6w9KQ08f5V9F7mFuwFEcOWFrwTrnfGf16dSQGaYByLg0jS1hEy8nmrjrE3iQrfUMFLFLppN2H5Q2v1ZcDrOpGEFNkrv2O3idV42L61sSc5/PKg8nrzeGeHRCewfbK6/HSllIrCbv3syt/3aIfDzHLUsQGt46Sn8SdrlmyR4sMzxYryHbM/M3A@j4KI324GjV8izkNkt5G0ZIIgQ3dDZErqwUQvHYAOacUBOB6kDL/OnJmaAbKJrjroTde/ZRXfJ12JeUAbs3TGPGq3@Aewo@lvpnjUIc1AmsU48C5xLu0uWO6ld4ypKG9uOHAPinhpw8cSxi2iAR91sf0svGv5l@ZtaxRDMWXEfOVh55qExINJLJSxq@jJzH7DcUb0ATBHD6M3P2t@o8f3OsAdh7vzw1FldEhk3Ilq4pw6PozWnT7RkM@QTwNB1UxL6wqn/I5GiueePk6OAoNYs4FRQXIY2PgmAZeiOCKTTbIF7IsFR30WTkXwDsApaY7Vv4lzZ3VHQymZ@CH6t4lKoQRWFOREqHYTtZEyRd5HcSwMORNk@lP0YPj/QJrMgL9OO06CHlPLCgL4XZRkqEIr2r4yUdo35qLBut2IqWm/eh@D@WoPzGXUMX17cyv@NUQCPTpj8@I9hz1sZWcQAEyOgw17/kYmaZc@bZ1epB1dHfckvUZ3kFV6rTBLxRTc3MqZy2qXa@5W8MNRjpw1WQ3uUlX1QjZu5zzracs0sZVXD8O0gHNM/I/8Iz4AiSY8c@mlWK1OclZBzzIjB3SoJWvBaUYRk0gt/Xrnrd0jZYXITMh@ffNlCEWgN4DPdD85sUhfiXluMuIir8TqiKPgIZg4tslYfHTIunM2xOwEgPOwyYchyD0yusEC0RHoHKovhqayD9lQBI3EVodxnEGIW8cj0vKyehNhzyeT4NAI@@OexLEP5FTLlPAkwIfG0HaX99Rrf0wod76v28Ji@UeHfRe2i2hMjiV0feRZafT7Q1IdffSbcHTbY8dT7/ShQ9ALr4Y6fiGtZ@2hPpEwSj81A7VJdu@8zEgAeUYtbI/grdD0mD@4S90AFqISnuQ2t6KyxLyGRzfMoWP7drGosuvxl3WiCYclZSKuqxX15YuUEoLqkKEBU7AdRpsLttnkdnDvEE2/m/7wI9Z@qEC9ZtCMIpNaIPksUAap1uMYj42RdH3QD/lEg4YCJyARJYpykBYZqtIa/VSzk7ZrSsfRMRG7lHvy4@1ETGqspaihmHF168R8KzkaTFBpSYcGjYKFFpeWGZVZG66vd27GOFpo8tpapU97kUhZEyWi/NCojngSuRk9vceTPuQvPwwxe@gN7ri1CgqEobPiXnVazjF@sCl41w6GTftMlDSZpj/A8Rtvffo95kVzdKjD/jX8URiMaQfQyLdv8wyjnv1L/7JX3@p3/It2v@3TPg0x4G9F4uFxzI8YsIth/ybkFEL8oWkVao7jZ4kvI2HY8Du6lyxZobnCUTDI2mYKo@G4cilhIvjkHEaAcfpS5u/BZIy0qM6T5bhSKul/yvZ4Rad0Z93HxVmV5UYfALSA25iwoBAf0hE7JlnOp6WpAuf3FbBwPFc55Tt3WOwlMH5GJOJrmATGBpkpswS7E9iZ3YnxSfPWbXIMwiECLQXbAdLhhFl@7frICE1S5DksBdZUcbVgVZVblFvEIcTD@G5yLz39B2NPCPwJ9IuPZ3HLLEZgEdcy0ZZC2a/oKKOEC5sHtllGsyQmKda@aPcs90POQHE7CTX5eXwXNdjyh5QiHWZviisxI7O08UGmu2ydRE597GBRWVALDsftgApSGWULdzNs8C37WZ78uMSVkzMIpi0NOWshfRepGkQl5NydMK@1UZaYyt@eMUtL3ztqEwQszzI5s3I/Z9NGc2EPlLasr7jW6g9JGKcnqKdNPRbCUX@w8J3Uu1N2zIzMNovWDcf5piGwMFuZFstHTSZteYzHcSk1ic8E0yQpxpZmxEPYvvJzxOaTRLwt1zHfyvXxN@hwF81iu6loUYnGuylzH4viNSx6zUITTSnGHUFKS9H7kzp1vH63BNEwZXtVZ4lRh8ioj@XRAjVBpohK308h5j6N@wQ9mkQ5tNsk2tnjcydRJ43kTMhT8ykR5BL0ROB2OG2SXBq0YHyBMHGi4UZCKlI4b90xX@UVc@cIMowPAhBacZCLz6HkBDcerAk@4uwArWwd1kJFSCJ62rAtHKKg/xHBOCq/PtzRFg/1ca54VhJItxEk2lVwqfsgGX9z@nlSv2UoU6SgKT6DFFGPpmTT5ff36s/2hcoRBKnNn7Wlb8FFZxy1SNjQP/an@i104LgpXTMxo5IToc6igeYC7VIuOoFsV6H9tYfC8bBu0NOINhDyOos/i7oGwnmvFCJqo8ptc4wijia3zDZH5TakSsxQ8hvk11NRVF3euBKAQDCm@uUiQUBYU8YelwIcesfmvASieoyoYrmIaUkvOSpqbOc54zuIqgs8WbZKFGaVeGbDyM0EQorF7DIxIqSzzC4SQ6GFbiYuVomns/sTlyCF2PC@UJyGQo9KkobRyAkBOdl0wYklyklRuQXNwfzxybKT@BjxN399VrC@Fia/En0iDE9yxcmvq4XE10SzS0vJqomaRA/HbjXxkUjh2AhHUuHP/ceuKXbI88gm1NpkJLQMbZ@NZOC0y6R9m/drqNbZKdvoGAae7Rlutl91SbGSCMp@fwB2tcBXBojd/qd7ayxTDSY6VwDHpTPOLlnZELLGmsZSj25hp2si7UUBCsyett9Sb492dhJhX8/HxtCoGwyXC4UCmPjcDn5vbKtxlNTu55Ol862rTic/uPnL8O15nmV/EHBKgDWzgw5oSGhShF5/eCGZIYADFUXpnHZkxV7/qtWyUzDghhKDR8MmJXU0BMULUDsyenl7xAdADFIvsL@gg@jfLyqafTe@KJoairmGotowCb5Om9szIg9etGCfHd1UMTAIZmPNROuWU974jBUEmU14sDh8sfM5Nk9Ovwo6nb6r3iEJMSIFzH2drLCzY1coSBHcMLJ371XI8WhdFVy3O5ZfMYrYvA5wZmEyeSZMXHjExj8ILqq3g2z65EOalhXq8iK6uYj41K5KX6QdHSz@O8AKHxLa31W66w@yDabTZGFa6vUMjp8Io8dFd@beJ1HE4TMxTbNvlwZRZ6PrcbAG6rrDuoCJZc/Dyz25o3hE3PTpbbEFGhYEhsYJMVe@rwZczf5xYvF61Gp9n1TkNAAysD8kESUTyp8TiHwHwDNQTz@iJ6Jo/zVH03pnIqCIKDhI1jEtd1Chjgqp1MNG@bebbKVSUfODxUVVqWzSQy6nKpsVtY0Xm5tqm35v4vdP5aXl5ZLI3G3nM73cNC@/qk2CwSeci43L4Tb9pG9l@I3BWhtDPJ8vz7ul@Xp5faMU5k8qm3Drp6f//Jf/@Z//@r/yFf3j3/Fjk3@cfIgKeZ6Xn298nv/pawm/T7bPFubPT@YHZwsXJXDZ3zhqeL82yvmx@ag3PE9lZBWw3rIdqdlnc/QZXVWZFIBdf/iRpMuayjTCfEa/DSVzFMvYTCOw3gfwozynLbxJOjC5lSckMgR0jON4Gp1GAAM8Wm@IkoQL7EClvtytmIN7hIOJCkS3KhkdiYd11usAPi1xJAX44tKKlWv3wqCHE/Br1nmle6mUT3/bo7rm3/yH1@HFZv9WPTrNqkcF9chVj9Jp/lNceUZvnfl8G965Uoy2A@m0S1/iqwWYGaqwzYoe7x84184EuVOpeU7ZA0gmTAUXFi84N9r9sbOMJFwLL1JzyMOp5IiEL5lQJfN5vveVhuUzlfiaTrjasKJQ17sYbsy6UYnGFyqQH4ohQNxyVwiy1qcmcdPHHsl4yps3eqxTnE2IAYOsBy93eN7jBa1F8z1t85zYSyHNEZvPy1usjSVxhma08UXajxHgCxXZThbYk3Ahs5ASK2@rl9xN8cK2@6eZT2wdxsHI2KZLpd@VxQRizW0Tbr6n/Vq0Ibdcr6h0O7pesZpKT9p@q5RVpXvVGbUH2l2BW8eE@hy19lVmEkaUAQkcidm/Nj3D@KDARIqaGBZJljVWzT66LjOhp13TaYAdT26OLCLkP2Rpbn@ZmNtOnr1EDDsIDzBSkSlfy293Qh11ZcjEvvCH58gO6Lc4odpI7s34PA/5VCcw7rcipD2GzCbn8XymrmQGQ/@i67sqs9c/GvrjGi1bpPmMGp5DPUQIJiCByaebntU9g7D0SA8JUyTqClsOIXlBZ6zTo8nYpiOfEwypmQo67AomQYKdmJLBl8RYTdAx5uofGAQb5SnhHd1GahHLkheWRhpS2nab4Wk2NXVSpgV77kQTJ50SVKOZaXhBV7rCQtvli1@S5B3ECNBtp7UXoHZFWHmG9rE6XQQ9P7E4DTop4@ifLylZFzGfORWlWCOlTJ7UYpzxDliRHvkhGQVC1iYTzig1l83OnYY6nVvGXkc4yHdki5/3VTtKQMcJzNgzRB332iIsJ1aoOAeGp2ps@U8QWh3/gvAb3/hjsOJpJvv8Qd45@XDaO3uUPe19Of3kMCZaJJtVNqcy@jLbSCw9V2hlzLuJn8YqLTShBk97yQKnPSU@LBYJCJF89uRD/uxLnhA6zSAl/WlGCJIYMmCSv7@9PMDnp9DMJLHIZ1JzziPHDH72edFRtLbyX4yhvHDkL2FhNpV8TE/7nGGLQLGf7m9X4nIS5leXCk@Wik9oJ3QR3OaGwRXW21x4dR7ckioRYjtLS8/ppwQ3JAjx9Tb0S/TylvopaU3E9yTUTkpahOppzu2kIraiOp7wBJUnKnO4VLi4OFEZH5eP2PC7iljOlOVYUGI6aHFfFutn2O@iHT@EXJv0DhGOhJWB2IjwEWoOkE3ylbs41DHTZYH9nDy1hditDISGN5@xVotev5fTyprjLZSgRMNrprNaWC1MztGpKZqYofNamVp4oIobz5/@x7/t/5YZZTaW8u@G9HeU@S2zspqRR3qgX4/Nr@vMRmYdxVa@ZsZ52gPT49P/@N9Uf@MvBAdfxuv0z8aygbUyzmzkylzlS2ZjhR6KS0vU7v/553@mPszLjg25WOfrrmLESoYiW36PeZe@qxp6KdvShVissGMWYIiFIe3N6QcMo26XVgt8TJfRVhXXgY58ZexR9BLPhlkjNhWSkwxjT0GakVQoo4GcgDQmFC1l2W4Ysw0wb4ym@uWhtxLSDuAXbc4RNRmZbjwMYTI0L9siGsCstEj7eXnYKDxPR@Yda2ljU1IyKiS2dlrWrj4uETu86QejdiNpJWGma7fh3wTnHvjQC5pXtKfqhZ3@r8P8NbFkt7i0mm/hcD/Pdtz5AUPKDcbeJ1IEdTIg2hiy0amrhjQC/S5CeLmcLYgU@p3oTsrkkyQtexA05AwrmZOYioiPnyvXw@iOF6vSWf6XFHhkztSJIK1caac9qrl/sKbSi1FBKcd7XgfYvGHjWB0CIyfWsAOWTV6K@4DTQdMfrzK8YCckroWo61LE85vNuq@/ZVNzaZMqzU3NXQadQTndkvDuiJ2KGxNNf1Ez74SSa@MEIZdjQQdY3WDk0xa9nOY32I/HLSBMir5rjULFxWRt6bJ6V98sc9aVe5q@kaZvaEShJcTtRDxjRWNTdjGRLWUcVQ6DOq7UZjZMrYUmafPQ4z/AIJRhqbXglqC7wx6QRLW4O9qqzB42l/fCxCM3gfjsydGiZK5OZWLnR9eUEA9q6E5o15PGSEAgCu4aLJTp96F4QJRNmtF2LyXx/CY@m/geGgz3YR@hRO2wdRJ8VJal3jVy37RH7EupiAQ6rqxtg52S1SMCHYXYilLQpnHwknbAUq013mxxQTMca5wG2oSESqflnOqkoaL0si2dvVYSRdCLdKG49PjJ8srT1WfIcjanezsbDCp52AUMLn2CwRp1ljbZeF8upxfS8gopqKebBPRZYHEBB7OuG8cxYZ9vnAflYkEDK6QZ1g2n0ZDq@riSQcYQh4GHFYH2KNlhOpt9vnaCjp2dNp0v9D/xt4kPyAxnwtH6QnprHN7EkalSXQk4UGbBzEFxso8RQcXRX@yyQb91gGgTAWxdhe2poV1EgBhdDvtXF5c2d3g6tNURTRgiOMelxg7qZTCKA4xZWEEX1QcONcv7omzgnUz3AEa5WBKg8wlwmmY6bqWvLU0xOxZoEUJkTXis4grRMh212Zm5s9dX1b3tScQydho6huvZlq2k3HEkMwSQQa5eq7tHRF0d7YJdSbVMchNRlVnAFVCuyO7wPnylG0hEbVHFyGrWG0bZ@8hSZF6MQ5vGVWkcgdcMmMXCt0lp/FpNL0AQIwj1aVIkxNzoPscmWYyTPciYp@Dl9JplI/q6HYYcYE43lna0RSkX4qwCc6k7AOLcppCWjhTWMKL8WOXEyzLaSOYoXtE4GtBmyNFONZhZktNMsNVtKAGwkXXc0AL9r@1tuWq7Sv/svNt2oShvVv6Kfkcpnu/Gt6jxLa6p2o4ZAjtaLNvcwmbqN7goEbMUdMDYGEEI35ZkRQziqAHV2o6mvUzqk8TcPou5AuzqayXcnI7qSYJAL3wGMqc371EoDnbX4Xdrcng1LWmikCp6WsgR1/0T26LJXNxqBElI@R0gliZBRIFaYm6fixleLNBZ8/b13sUwdm1nNk8nWFY2VKS27@SJ7EmevZMy97HFkmaLpTWM4318wXx7L2@cB62@9kWLmOMbvPHgj/FG7vuZI/ffgjmq/xjueKy54/EaZI9wRxQ2nD06OQ17fwbHnI95Da432xdtnA@1rJ/oRMG1ALDAA4bwIaWPxQL6doc4UdnZHxYn1yMYCS0twzHgD3X@ie78kzXIXH7cDv6rdj73d@78su788hrWmhkjr1U7K9z636fHsUqYTb6YObxQd6WY80d7uqJ7urKG1XTGMP9/72nu/1FPn@qePl1DxAS5cJDw9fdzs2gilcOtWi02t/BSOmhXFnnsZ3Olg71Xs5ymzUOrcxVelqGtqz@M/6rGfxXSiJ@Qhg53EZFtaLSXl@2pOMuLZsmnHApOVtIT6a@JjG71Vy9Y8X5EL1AipPlga6g3KqSQu/Ixvm3yYv0xlr7R4vO9OIts18kycXFubaBlR1h04ikumq9Okrm0Eq0r2xwDWW0dHewu/g8hQ9f/qL3QCHkM7U3Q6ZiVxN6CHUVRp3RnrO4A9qHecyRYRZOTkR1pb@@IXebulmoc2GJiXZy9SZCrNtz/0V6qC33DysqNIyOijafrm10VTHPN9kLeUN@l0Owu6x7/IS59prn02Zo60BuDu0jl6wM/zYvxPm1pefm@NUBqefiDCVhwqfw9s@r/Ag)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/5v68i)

[Answer 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102395) is for the [Bef](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93) interpreter (Befunge-93 reference distribution).
FBBI is separated from Bef by reading a cell outside of the playfield, as described in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146544/hello-world-in-multiple-languages/147056#147056):

```
         v
@,,,"361"># 23-2g_"01",,@
```

Get contents of cell (-1,2). Bef [returns 0](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38hY1yhdz@H/fwA), FBBI [returns 32](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P/fyFjXKF3P4f9/AA).

Answer (score 3):

## 363. [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 16064 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8;s0::&&1Pr"93"pllasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrlop#std[]!!92[]?42>805在ｕ=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD440TD@0ekQHWRFAmAAL9JkSqVStWl7qpWTUnV3W6SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uNl5suXL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuyJY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3R46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbEsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6Tza/fSjK/HVDPtIh0KNLWN2JXtVZZ@bhtu7mkJjnx0/eHDVN8s@kRybPbheJDXHdqcT52ByFX6e7Q4MW2eaXJa1q4EFQObEsEqZUuZqUBHa05iY3aV8IOCB6ULr6n4rsq5uQ2thW24xYzSezJnE21@3rLBtPaZ7bOpNdYvi2dNRx3CDiN5EdyemPWBn5mTIJkPTC9NRbG@sdw2pZ1jmyJwYPWaZkMjp@1AAtN1jJ8b8zHGhyX2Yjm3NIaHRNfsmJgnKAQDxSkyGBocz0ufQyPYEiIPpzINiWEYALSnEIP59ozMdMGc6GU8nDMrWMz29YwHQzpz1jL4@tSZp1oEwQDL5nw0N2ydmACcDiGOHl@rllIpmLGhe7/VYBugYynFiMBOwRsWqsGwW/JnjAtYgVlAiHxjRNa@jMYM2gybqOxWWz2QgfD/0wdLqluf4hVkuGgba0FepzRDuE9cZuPoIsNEzCKefHTxhXtdx4Q1@GJf3p5vAdPUJ295m8f1P78dZPWwW2e0IYRPV2Dk0QSwIZKe6NQUKibaEA@3jhqkFbLL4RrzC4oAWLcNyOZaDbltiWh6QpGbK4ID@r2VV@BWYVmI5FXpQPp7GfPquPjAtg0MZIJQiEr6WZxrcMzmWVUs85sCx@jxalzIrsmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYPcEHSOqeU8/ArwA2hlKIoKv2yOA1rQPdAp0toe6@sj05r70Al8l@VVVgSIUF4VIGslgADPbBZ/WfhRsZavKOzJELA91E8BvGSZJ8iNjJAhYRMq8FC2thTiiMhyefbeELMH1AHS8iVWhOwLgIkcFAEwq5Ug@3yGV8QbGpblJxt6mIxKW8zAD0peBDyUAPsZwGUGkVmEH7wDv9OAsWnAxTRgTBowE00DdxazgHgFCCtAUxZ8fA117wQy4vloPUI@cHQAoyK2kYmpiCSAAK3FstBmBZYDQsgiIeSzDMoPZSkWGPCxkspKOVYqMsBnOcOgbVQoF1KJCvxThfKoCAzaXwUCUKFMKmBbBaBqNs@ECLLVLIZD2iykBdSoOUiTAzc0nFrAH6QDylAhSxXy1LTyggihbFoe6pvPEnVqBWjdIoQB3jQoqwbkpEFptRKEY9oS4LCExFuMpzkidMQDtAqSO9AhICMP5SG4EBfcWjHL8adb46HeQW7NU3b6mLSA3aCAaISkGawePHOITShKBsBgL4Dia0ABWUBHFpo2mwuzt1QA0kDwRs8kBm2ZwLvUEEPFNBHkS308WaBNLVCJxvPJMPTTuJ8DjNME5mcM9O48DITelw4DF76FLPpqxGsXgDI59PWAszpTz1oACR05jbIyTk1r4Vciv56h9/qmN3yzKGuOMukY@sQ2Txa55PPpCFL1SEABA5a8itlo3IkpwXA1GKJrURetiHHGTthAS0VWVSpex@hP7YEhlUuR8lHIZOpOYGBZ5Fnm3q45GMCYvICjpqmaNFAuvPNUQiubnQihJ2IX83RNGL7vsO4QBIowsMzhl8sLGFkNYcz1Do7qEkhhMAqUcdzqmzPWudOlUWNRwCzhqTs0x0HkytrIkcalTGalQoQ2CHOvS5mQNePVkl86pp2Is3hSuBRgrOGSZXSkhgHtcxylcNxF0oVx1SGpYcE@E3YwMiYBacuDPIy6FrBRaJSujiMwjkcGjacBHHMiM8gExEDDOUWxlQbFpWw8Gjg7LkqpIOX0DNdlGBdEWy9NQ6w37XjGqynKUYty9WHMNmBo7@umFRaAxhF9QgIAPOMe5DdfLnbfdUY02IxwCLUcZ7xGXIEB@wwBPXTOjEXRF@O5Ph5bIDWBv8GFNijMmU7yNgnn0Vx5gSARpoMGB4CUFUgbpmt0Cfd@1SF1FuSS5SJWmFa/k0Uo9yLiVBY6C4gaHqaxp5ZVATnH6LJsXekZpwr6cJFrWdTCMgRCGIhSPoiODrIylpxKEUK6o8kk3h0HLes5o@Wq8fH1IKz60ETByDrT59B6fRhajZk@AomeodgMPZeNgGJ4C2JLgM6C1TpgPceOT0IoZy4IsVDpsCYkKCNOJubIAO3HgSTY4jkqNI7uVLLOHEiZsJWTSd3hJbmCKFm4iijukYt48M4C4l5v2kWsYd6mTRQEYpKHMr4LrJL7CROXNZs6/FyQ58a@hiejAyMeYdEiCoLHe7sveXcJIsqohu2BWuHJzET9Cyh/4PSB2M5MqDswLEi6gN0lJCAKQq@Z3JUFQjkS0OjEYibrjscM/GFQAvJ8kCmBCOq8NNlrCLSGoEJ0p647Z7MxtIQ5gliTrtPvA/W@NsZDAMFGPdadd6F7QiMj9Qg9hxhMd7xczcXbpgFxbFRK9p78IhsYgHYQWPuonSLJLyowHlMVCBW6zYVZWwdMYRW64zmhRYgtUvQdR0b/nmN4RCyOexJ2fczMMwbUNaCf9RfMaITCOVCpTUpFDziP370QPmYorKwMZuVTwUeGDV2nC1QJnR6aD9t0l/VByY6IsKhn6N2uMZ74dOIQOzPtiLx/@ADlffKVfGCyNxQ277LtK1QDUUPKiciyqP9g0ce@GqIjr/U1eYkEj1Dl5JzFml/LHmKcXsldfIFxlkrwQlxThjF1CVR@iElMJ8hKkDua3SHywglyG5K3obe50@vVB79o9u6ISf0wbyyNCmxHkJXQC8uxHoYEP@s6IHlsIaz6kgdGXfK4BbTujVZAdsJCWr2or6zoMjDF24COHNtZARWQGcLFKMsh1BZEjEfINXQrJEbqLt5SGyHDXkwu4UAGY@h47LjQMzjTmdNMAjVZhLp8BTwRjhVJmd1bHlphyIjjgD/BURASjC0daAG7GPZU0Kx04BTAxLiCDDzP4TlGCky9nmD55Tsj1s@JCcZS2zZQOdPdOQcC1YPhGTKaM9N1gQ2e4iDBx6BgMJGJTmFM0Hs95KyIDur3VzOXkaL3ph1zdlUL76Kn/NITTnWX9VEBd0HogE6UiPe9eLJK/pQyEiQqzniiUFJ@FyEiRZKhyRN90OlhkHgAjOZobncT4lIXE9NMnE76JTEJDkzIZTT2MagKV0uH6gMSzegE@jW9VdkAhm9JgruEflQSDFBkDNBdkDOgE4KWWS73Ojq7AO7hMmm2x1WRQCVR5VyYl2H3wrx8RGBZovWVeRae2yWHFBnVsAYYnWpOg8QSAt8RE5RQBA9F8cdW9CBpj4eRXMM9pzbNw7EEF0WS7DwUfmEASFBhTBA@zK45afviyp07geCyUasBsYE0BWyzl4xqtMGEpQycGiLLJI34mcgT52iCfSORhPpi5EteGhCbgFJrdXY@GbrQ4@j9UoBIgFbBRkoOEOu386fmybR3taFt9MRIIvY6EJrM7kSsCjD4895Quwmr8SWsgtYbR6wi8WJ6An2NeMkXG1T0o7mGh@JvzS9KpIUTWAKfVleiiCf1/RYEvTfvWr5IwF3Q2Tk36kDxT/yJrJARpX2ZIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT3aPH9b8vsgDlY5pV5Y8LKerW@S9idHFIO2jg3tPd5/@YnsFDMvsVK56KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2JhwOY4o@MFMcmYRUWnehcFlFqDz8OknV1ECkhCig3IAN/6uiDQ8DghdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDLMEkQl0kHLIAZOrDoGK4H5Xkyff0aG@9qoca@P5bMmuocQOCpHNhBOhkDrwhgQVCnz0dESgtSqGnjQsPCFY0ZlOcjlJqvFoZE6QjJfHT4YP9pjcD682oSRVG8CchSutuTgeatKajgq@IA@wNXl6XkRcFRnqayrkRwt7uE4EXbsjXwAQDqOrLDJGsUVM0bQtn3rtaNfKVuSAH0ThCuypVReaj7vgWNlAOHuC6qvKtGUQpYDFah18oRKwxdHra6@bxRzJWjw1Z3kWcvCpQWBWAcCORGF4JOPAl95IUU6YvVfvGPHl0ruEdCJKgCUlAyz2Iy5eVZAmovksninrIHGppjGfLnxPFEJiYVJR6sC8hdj5TPSPz9mTlJZJL8qSYhLuS@u3ug3Q8i@1PWNJNBSgPq4jgyuX1c3@t6QCO2YzkDh21BGi4dBhmC2LS2mrsDx77WQjp6YlVjuEQI/BcnbvQxjDXma1IcKVVUXeWLjbrtnQGXVgtZRBJhiEApFF9@qZ/qgK5FvY8OvtyHQUTNZzKhO0MXoCCShtCFrm7ElzyYBBnJfnlWVjBcLrzW24MAKbJeh5X2GV2YcHcRvNKTOKasrIy/skgfO9cw/tKZXyEt8OGkBY4Iyg4@ffLo4NP9x7tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC4A4yK8DspA85HjD3rrFuyZWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyL8AaquELrYmPnaEd95JXK3OGodJLu8tJ6DF2Ph7VTwiKds9CZcTlq9U4niP9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedl1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQoojDc3eAo@uQWiw5xmEHVr5IDyQmveyBpYgoOnWSvLHAxBF8aFccNNyiEFU22UHmgIoCsrYd2IAdMb4NZ/Bu0kctL@QNVKnK7VjJZTxCDaUveHuBt9A1SnBIxWgIrklVfWvNO8w@bApRHSVSAxJm/RJIfHcCywGAiSNGuKen6AHOIWOF@KvIJw9GqKs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpk@5QmjgSwJOcPs0bRKiw73V1uy9v@Y6gsCD3fQhVzTaeN5t2CwT05h0qG647N@athtpKVtn1JFt@/GQVqHepeki7gQfQLjmBNOnJ1vCznn6dnfV06l09pkxGY3/Mkcbs8S4IUq8d4Nc9I9r3MIESDVS2luIqGPmNsmJCyMKkAt4QUwp0KBhpgfQULJcEQi@Kh0A5wLciCdhiNoPXg@/viPARVLqR7k0n7tEaCco1OFvqjQGJNNncRS7t4fzgBEbHkPKRS0PjIpNmZ0Yc59F1j89WQiJ/jT9ID7paCIFm5cMZaTvc1QBEQKlIPQfOAXSF06bDxSwjKv1AaZAhlQknH0CCsGn1YAB8BhLziuzyivCcyGe5Sie2c2YjtI7BSlLHnPDJfmfq4lq32YvWDaJnNR4HoFHlInydFsU7RpfPsvLEVAtQAnU2MkYOTiWAdEWswKAq6HxBHXVBD2esoVtlJFwxBPgSu7sHXKxr8PkiaYRKFJDUPotPXGVX@lLRpddAzTfIVlj5SBP7jX4cIGB5ewPNkvgzoCSdOCOK9DnNt2DgvUDcFXDFEGoMFCbqNWds2Fd1Pq4RJpJV2oYQj/NFoPP4xsZGvBKvx9Pg2gHXNrp20JUC1w65JHJhPBldlCJNLgxtUAr0a8UvGwHkWbKFNDBDyeG1OU7ojUol20rrDdV/avhMQlMA5iG2hA@AE0/WauhMJsX6Ga7ZgPweqfse0s5R1zXHPgo@BoGAv/s4yBISQL1Had41qqib3oyRUc0FpdFAETPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpTJ6t6DfRDYF6TxEgeuM50DIJbI1eRgLclG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkZ5MflhKpnSO60TcAJpKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQTn6JmgZlpWIy@clyL@TbCVTcUibjKeBLdficcALLTh6VGmcEeBE9MCcASqhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb80xsO5G40QzrqBlI0z6Iu9KrilB7l4lEu@5umjAt2Sph/IvTweCLc4eYfy0njOubvAS9pUlnZGBePuqdQfORNd@UwGpUmODJfxjbgiSTASUgiHRNV@bHrYhXXbcKZedKZx5QQo5g6@x8MpMMtge1oaqMocC0Z36LD45l2AzsL1HhxKcOlK4gtgAYBeV4YfMlGUSnCxBKQL2lBkAl@krVg0K6NSITjrCebm84XxKznMrUppWAYzMge24xoSoARSCLR7ivbkCfVgXfqAZr6urUv4oTSkoeJtGsARH1iOTrjl7DqyHjQeRdKDfg5Jnho9wQL@0Qf2KPO2cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNogJ9bC1hr5AYrjjXvyZAZJhQQOuNFArt2B0HnGepqmFbr5fiUIQ6oAZA@hkVArtUHFDYIkFQKTfiPv82mhQEf/9PD@Pp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U5Epfb3pq2IM02wd6Mm1nZAIagvSvT6ynjjPhWj68rJuZ4UqzOZpaOs35XJ2WuTFd1@k4Fk0F3ZR0EX/qerql80moIHT3s8cg6z87PqrJlUgkRT8d3Zg3zkOuzpbj8yC65kjrrcHykMcJU9zMizhuBbs@kc34AQUMmPp7PqGNAv8i@gddCtdQfP8S@o9wvyfIyv4sAr2Gnn7EMkXEPaC44c33PFczl@i/VgcL46kUjwuOi9Keqxr5n076/SXvLHmfSMiarIV3jrz5XtAlHTFapDyPhBtDl@JEARUoTrg/dG28IsXju1vkcGXxcbgJYWhYwdLiU5BYcPkMBn0L5SpQWlBE53s4DZCwx7hKQqwb195YF4RQ79p8BnS2scRjC7EN6kAwuCko0gibCvPnvqvUhWzHX7P0OFt1QOenaZXtOl/lRp3K5eqcwmflN9sAYrteDTbcrYuGOcXjYTSCSmWDFFRNWti/VtVwm4ZHk@0CJakKngLqxEzLSM1Zcb91EVc8QkOfic3m7MOM9gXoJbhbcvOOMjCqtMdpDb6qQUjcl2E7cyaBxIex@MR1dwh8hqVmy6iE9pnafcfqSXyVDAiGcf0KG8jfpBDu4vQ36xqmG2zgpB20PCny18jez2twrzRp/XqEyG7REBB0n3N2cZI@vWANGPJOZW9smZMWu5QnTnvo75Syr@4r5TKo6@pzT/D3uNTY7tOPPmtkWhyCMNJx5avEW3EWbE8GwRkEJdxHDi7cqTMxJyQJ0E4EE@urylCoGS2SQPEBBs@gysKM/Bph0S@Mi0Vd@gZoqgkDS@7NR2lmJC/lvqVPJobNaY4vP65HN18n8rOpUfY7/qJDhWVoZQYkUxPDoIhVdnR8f//pUxko10vE93EFpwLdUe8OQUBZV@kAk9HKV9iHvTj7ENMkUW0XoKuB9tH20wNRV4HoQf@A3JF3DAw3AZ5JXHzpgjetd1FCLqH5CML9Vt0J4SgEljCSUCcCVllZ/mc2V7X8claA4lOESUB34k4FcGsm5altvpI9GGhIboUoca6swnhR20wQF9tUk/6GuhEuHYOGRUIj1KDRYNJr4HIQWWStVpXvAYC4qIC5A8SuKFJT0C72mho0fQ28QaQhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM34DO6x@BixCWQXvGymw3E9Tfr3VkXga@Fsg59zNSp6@cvqiwTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TBHTof1Vy/uklndhQSdDVkJTMViRgCXE/OMBPs1SOHF@0HkwGXkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiG4VMYb4zLQPoExPXKgNo/8owFR6YB6q7@RBPtsUxADNWt5pRZDuAivnF6RTqVTMZqOS4emfeLQek/oamdkNY8SYZh6dGJdT4mbUOm2FDUsA4@rrSudN@r06bYiAi17@Avq5EET6r4sDEKkrjylB82tr8h5eRPJUrb@9lQaacHNpFe3xJTKJYrc73TMdVEBCbgvLHiuiAZMCulZk3OyGpw1wKkYGI@AcXHtZVH1q/uP2BLe/X20/vM/f6MH@L/eOkMYKHDmMXS0YejGlpL6axvLT4ovdFvdsHyCfGqZOiGGXLeB7OouVEm3Qsdq0LQIL0kw/I9wScFvcaBNvIHUeAOZ8ZLzFcHguTqTVYtqNrDM7rq4V/Zj8axo@QcUux4hgQtBpkGJiHXxRjBmfAkmomIjG7u9UMGmKUbEzNt9OJ1M@R0E11sb0Rzj76a@6cfM5PWOaih85/oNTe7qJ9OeI41PBqGcWlgRd1F7WgOWQBzwl4Pb6FxdfV5BvhM8eK6LthjalDN63EYVnj31xlKHtPAef6OOMLohB9fi93VRTP/wXuhYjzXTots7UqIPHQjF3w2h4F5TKYI08wqaLb0zRxlk@P5UFu4sAI5T66ZSmeyapeXxeH161CQpfbm8OvVM7nJ8rJojUPh@VonPolGF/R2ut7QqDFfmSLckrRdxrmXmqzYmXIsarmlSGjx8QScwbiRyHJC6U0t3F64bSHxRjmAZYd2MtD9sPDG7DogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gat8gItxPTLbL9wVyFxuA4iRS6VrMApzvBLaNraOodGBrfqokbYiNEIjvrMNV1zvC3VnwYgmrK76tHtNcrS/UOzEmyupYO4/ja4WBpchAnH28h1DPTM@i2GrEnKws66Vor/Ze7QDDtF53Gu42sPdNyPHZE95sQNHABC/y@mqCjuDR1W6LJ8Kj7Bh4U7HFYNKhuDRyrUBooOtzWtvrU7SPf95/vyuFCDqWqt3CoQPxxbNV/ruXrJ4p7clsD0YFFF/e3Rpw3DLGr2JS/9rK@dqAY4MLd6po9yJQopazwqb41GeOSy5k@D54/x9CxDrXB0DGekzgN0h0mKJfAMXG5iP3z5Ja7ObfeuzGla2CLt1Ui0rgnlgGDFd2vNSnTMup7plAzmXdnUX1rakyNlYrGYeelgcfqb1Ay3r1QGb8am/5MPS4O4NGUMNZrXzN8p1LjOI1vNzIT3TK7xu2izDJTG4P0PUbV@Qk4nqDjeoqBPR0vteqSdmY/vRllw3HQpZ3eUukw5H35UOkWSWlJPvcM@t2oMXENDzeI1fKZTMYXYCIrLksvN2lS2TDtS5PflzImn0XOi7i4yuZGnKvzILREtyCuZUHaOsWeIpfLim3axmSO93fkph3Hsd6npYCp4oFhB7RVibba3tRi18Qd/xAJW0xdeDjh0emvm7Tgo42vWwJ@UGm@qdGjS0Lv1JoSLnqOcEFq@fXm6ZvIAtNtueDhVpwT4ptvrfWypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqtMxLJ0/ZoXcTfDKcvZGeMtMw1@sxcVdvqS7WIqPXWFK4zkgy@yBljI0Rga93iDl6z00keE/1kaaOfhbFzwzjK4y2ze66yKMTeALNt6X1pAjwtLEsUG/muA@P9RTLNxJ6vuu48DBqt9KJB@M9IHBbbbcxCkXExa4m4ardQvn6qmLCt9B04VkC2Mc60kCOtWJMfeC50qAj@ddaNfp6Pbptiudv4tzoO/Q29dtYb0@xNpDZ2gPjSHfNx6@rescQI8TbmPnpqJDqQdD3Mo2Hi9tcY/i03Is613wiayRM0rH6a8s0z4efsWTW@8Fl5@09x@3Tt7pE8470LG21wyNKYxLnjNxxoZEb@uiWjjRw@/reGiwSP3zziDdqOcDRoLnzwv/Vt1yoDuT8Zge7bE19ehGSSU6s3yb3NTnW1NoU6TjDuTXzqgj@56yv2@FlsBXs5iOOekO8dA4p2xj4HS6Q/O2QvuGKpRgyoe/vpPuipgxmXQfvWXLBPS6cxnppRYNP8LHwbpG92eP@LAWOm6QV1bN0NGxbGmsn3Q9PhuKLlbBCeFIb@SHtyt0/L3yampOFkAje5nC6V2@LIGOdWX3d0@slazojMSCDfu7KtZSKQnpKJBLRgYEHnVdtsv73CJdLJvlt3UFitaSShTZl/I@6Pb3/tDsoBmZtwX/Jfpa2rS0cpCzh9OBd51h8un6HohoeFs/bUF7mSNT1jBm6bb/WIdmzVLwkCM82yBzTY0b11TyNy6qUDzVknTHhEcbHtB007VzaJY59vidSf21S3H@XibQxa@uF3LczFcr037D9Iw@XwJB120i4shxcScyyCBSF1fScQYdmTkXvDjjsp0BMHXJYovIQdx1YsvKbUKrmz8cM6UvPjUGOu61fmROcLPmCqogkl21vehW2F@f6p759SnUbB2xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeI/1gdl9uNQQYSF9BPs7PfljifzR63pbnA1ND3c0hY4bJqaQ5DgRI9W1QW9YEfPqvH1orGLRgfgxyJWxV82tO@M5nhabk@umaXVzQrOs/nOd6rhuE9iNhTibjsZTz3@sLgPtmYrOQo9OyN87MwG49ApYKxvq1mT1THVkyhWkMH9QXDjXSeNfmpYzYF@WMgyENhDCUDhfQTj3YHh@ghtyXHsFJVLe77jsiRMdkssr9gra1sgyybTNyc2zOZMJbs4JnlgZPnLgCQXlEd7lu@8LQTpejZFHt8v6i6PJt4zvQHlHztTtGugM7Y1E1QI/V2Mv2H2MJzoctJdyFtXSuo4F3Qsc1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtamImTAEl/ff/wsGaUG2q19mxQa2CNbuNZuGLhCZKYNgth6ProcO9Al7nM7SU9pq/AtaXbRmFOX2PV9Z5W@82QOA8g7K0zA/Kej@0YXlw1vzftT57FjOzAajYFRjp4a/Mz/0kaP1Qkx2SM81Q746d2azRGBXTMIcWlDHxsdaF9r4XqXsYgDvq9P9DVDEc0Nkv4Xum6lFdPqGO5LmvSLuNeptMsFemjMSLdYTzC8D0qTbpeLxDgft9RHllZsvLHj2PxO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vftCuYwb8ZfmBVbqZ8tVPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6urtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxySQvrwbeUjxRh6yUI1Akj3VPVqkX61qLECqs/fYAjTU3a6DK2G@44bdORHDBLew6XBvP9840AHEz4Bj6d2pbyz0tmJZo86IbmsVhkhrPjU6eCqoQ9Y8JvrsemPymSHflEFkR1doACBgV9ipCyzxBLSR5O3D1pIetYxVc0w34tRrl8tps45km0b3tY6zZg7hazE3vRQOdVY@JeeauepIN6JZZEWnk@4re9Ly1jUQaCxDmgxd0PmVyU3T24GZlRXrIdORgYvMy6swa0VXxxtSZZ3V6@khc3UNybf1B7wktPvH5UNpd63kieDh//DexwoMwu1CLjA9Aqzr9hV8KPzUtf3Hu1DgE8eb9M3ZIZQbTwGsYydYrTwkgQfvGejaWlcJaD17avHZh0Fk39WoR@qYRFaYJckidj0xJMM@lcgQ3Ox6jRx@6EvZReu9E6Mn@XYQcKVBehSc/wqj@c8VC6hR3oibPVWFI3ZWyPnbP1ch9yzgDCBvORNp7NFTGXtPDh4dHstjT105Pu0O8XTENTluybCCVspEpqRe6m5kvZNvR@uZ3kS5d6RKe48OZIywBt98RUOCB67MLT3WznsGVlwVfa0WhKHGZLWA@PD48aPU4ogmS@wNXWdkJKPBe0dHaTxp8vHRyuBo6gfQO/rObG3yg31VTa4g32c2rQ6u454rcloH6dgAbRSI8SG3y3KrcNV1xkbveD42PoPBEzm4947ZF9ZW8lP91BxgL2TltYiijsrKciGXjOzMBmXbcMPnuvY8McfILbv0UPhj7XYUlByyiptdLT3ctOJ/VYphGX8nwvslUjPXqTVqR1jRvb9vwVRVXYfnI70P7cryaxtrOcKq9WHLOX2HpWTDV16k0EuaAFVJ5q37yIvSCFi3gjecnvc9wdlZuw3mJgChd2Flhz8z7LluS7SWdZN4UYHUuKntxihfGu@wIBXu8DlFY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8paMj91Ikr29ewe3JXjq4/LmWB99@ow90T00QnJzxGiJjXco8UIyeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV/rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFoZ2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1eNVV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIcHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@3tEzQwVkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtbQRblFBo/kSm30kTHD7Sh8NniVUr9yfCvcMPYVk@uHk5vCSjeE5W7I71oYerKsnFFvAJi/IYzl5TD4kWOdDR15T3cNb8X@45UFuqki5RsqUo5wZ99aOi0s@u71Ij4eXfAfK6n12Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lXXY7aORSfYYjaVfD/e3U@gubW8ZOP6RD/6@Or@zqbEyo8f669UBxGlOVgYBEzSGUzoScT14eYG0AzKvYQ9Mbl@R3XMm@/R2g2IWnnhevRfBHN@fjteXGHgjfpLiKjtfivg56MzOmcfu4dG4hZi@QvfH/XGr/dfJtCycGEQzow@PdwPqOjxStEiOi1J88WTJGw@PTg6PIn6uMZutU3ql2TodcmXIItdPj3NL2W7Xn5@uQNb680YgbgA/Dp9r5SDO7D4@us4SUH0bTkZWEPKxbi9mTJcarOdM6KThysAn8xlto1zZ0kO@i21VmNtd4b2k2MOAbJqQt6e022hZv91eR5XHxhe09gBiEJtwsYQD9Q0vGbPcMCghJVnbUZ2ThfCzVNyj8dC0ZyuDRuvS0C7SxEtvdTfYZUeWc8YehVaF1rEHbTVw/dSw1zGnVYcVpXL2Zikse0WkWtcu/Osl/mNlk/Dzq1D9qO1zL@1br@HnvfkpW08ODNQnEnYqlUwufw0oemQYLQQnNtFC5iYdD4a4Fxdswz@SCwFicMjXP4SMhvRMe2rgKWL@jZBJbROyqdXUfJnt4Od3KqAAJClH9CJzZUFeDbZ57p@vrVTUS7ZRY2JFZP4J59D6MLegC3DR9ifUiUknKtucQMhmcDqX0ccg2AWjSQXQYtR8Bt5kJWqnoOqfX4YibZ4/OXiyf3S8e/zsqJFpXfrnm4NK2DbkFlhR@DDbE6HuPtpAWOH2tOlcvQXZ0YcqcDLCC@rF8OM3y1WrLVVtUSlxB9Nsntu2otARb0W6hPJJIs@NQrHLgReHHdSY2sc/3V/hp63p0Dg0EQctUp7QZhWWWZXxWIeBd9P2w69@K4pC8VtiFfyaGGbsm0AGwh04Ts/P0TPY7VeQ44Pdg0fPnu6zoIALojkze5NhrZznFrK52Qlop75Je95qLO4niUNb1WrxB3FATFyOswodyifr1EDnEC3ADh7n91NvscQmwQcMxsNGUf7zN5TLuIzbt5MQNx4UKg7ZAskToWxsbLBjIBJ2/@nBZ/tPGZZ//z55I4oQBDvGE8F/9uMe/75DYLEn@I6aO6JRkiyeCFGrAMFR@cVpfsQ5dd3x@q@p0fcU6Mx8@CGH8Es0gkDf@QC6PSNje1cMsSXJNhL/@ptvJy/IiEgosAmPKwVo88712KnpmXhiH8vQRxN0y8SOm4vI7KLMdvFTcfhBOp0@NgJFn9oTbubJN/YSA0qTQ5aTZptUWP5pEjESMb69AcTeMUCAYp5twnA8qbCXQIk4G1/hFh0kqR6/liQAXSGXhINuJOI1m3We0nSVt7/2T5RBlYF7Au7v@O5Z5h68/Yr/1gf3r3L3cwUJ7bqNu0VZogVCu5R@DXhBQvwj7iNfyLO5FY0F4tAUX8BXmTmCZjolrGN0ngO/S8COF3ASjc@g0YDcoMV86xk8P8NtJdAwZkVRkKRQqJfp7IIx4xsJrxjILOQLOVWBQkqnAUCyaD/AE9IcYDJZgW4inJrj2gsQFLe3t5mImr1RK1R5yyqb9vOs@CIs6CbEFc6GWLgGgzSQZJECwup@Mhh8UmoSkyL3iqtxZFw9B0YlCsfRC99tHxEiSwCyOI4MNJE@w48pTtx5YOi1g58fjHztZNMHJKkwJpErKQq@3YlPnQmQD3TSxfeMuN0J3EjLR0C0oOjxT4ySfVWkR/l6z1oclw4@q@L3NRl5AAeVzVwdTKNtK36OII4QREVcRb6N56w5adothdMmAzL94QpitsH9y8pgDc3yeu9et66ZuGobE5HF7h7ZDk5hPIDKsISmaFlFLSQXVcrlVlbJr5GfDVQHTfhcQHbApoBldA3zpTP2dvf2Dz4@fHJ0zYIkxYxfjQZ8v76dakpyutEKHfFotZab5N4D5ejxvQdBQywKXYhwY2D8fk3Um2qymJlEkIuTLlertqqEV2u3vsSf87PwV8ub1W4qGiW6Vg418x750m5z6QGdGbuauVZaha18/qYiLeApEdB7/MDvtaImkueXjdZ2vWnH4tcpYUVHeB6Tt7ATgKvpbW0qSOzXK4cVCz/@e4yfVfOifTG7ui@Km1k0UIb2BibOycKEm@8RCYjUN8gGWKQgK0HUtb3vkMvoC0ODGv84MbdsFrXbFClwIXMTxiOgjoPvHCMXWZhJ9S2EDkH1tcyOENjL4pZCA4OGoZFQbusqkRT8j23wjBP@l49nlZlMW8sSSeR2BCvNbjI6GsBLCtChUbp7MgXt7okz5sbXaQvBfSNwPXWA/d6f8ikHg308HUG8Pj2eGrScA5xbgsSAyXhYVC5LAZfwbY7OUmjVFfJroOVRv@LyqJdPzJLy0Jj1zAHw9kQyDRztQ1VtsdAuKVaa7JDacZHabNEKN3bFj/AYdxTt72WcdrYogN7QZdPuGbNE/CyerLQgf/SPn31@Gk@Kq2iJjOT6VmN7V63lhsUvqjdzEn3i987AFO0qblEuX@cS4HcVMLfaFnz5qVyWh55AX/KroeR@NHEfgRPEiER/pI9ZYmpzi3cyo9dEM2GnyRSYVOfWNG2WSpFCBQ8KkBml7JOLj98J3Z6zhFLDjz2Cr2f38PHaHLOGKsstcFMmSbaJX2TbA4kLbUAmBdCBIUmFwNaQhEDNgBLxTiJzAoc0GA5x4UF2A1cE0weqaNbbQZxQrVn9Dot8YW9ZchTL5YrfoMtcscyA@q6zQ1kBsNf4XCDXA3Z9YziAM1B/ZSG2YOTXOV6M8o3xgjz0rehAcWIRC7iBcR0GsBb2abtDF3@JfRv6CsgHlcqz4wftUlIRWWiNZ@CaPVyV4UbcQxXP/@wOdFNlKWq8yjW6jzAZ2j1sc3M/aH7vAXUY8QpLjUXRcPV77gvaVNUbqd5P6LcCxMzhAOCfWmwH4NBWZTBdsyJsNbP/2c/wi/FiYlNVT9ruaSqez1ThplbzLM8@3GxK0mYjU7u7qYMWNXk1a4JOrmzl7p8aw37vYKA0RZFlWU5Rts7Pz@MPtp6Yz/OsIPVMrfBqNr/MFrKvZpdZtfTqZKwWGvKrWUss1dInLfbkyRdv2m@S4ux0/kpsJrTY3uGFqOZQ5Y9Vyux8p5CNnZRB/YR8GTthr@E66TP8J/frXsSto7vTBxU2LrJYs4mfexeLoqI04i34J3X/BVxc8W/U5bq803rzJtnQ9clszkzTHHu9HvycIUiQWvKIgb58Bzg9T6CwJj1Jg8JrNOtfn0/IMzbbNQaD6b5e1/BAq3y3XZ2b0weTx19@HlzP8Hr9NJLstf8J2FQqIUmNFfMUlbaej@HHZP/sJxuX6fMn7e0/@@ZIMTbwcYiP71w@RveRmv9wY@PDe/dyubSmadz95Msnv7i7u5u7n84/aeR3clJmY/tP/2RjQ9O2NWWj5XlqK944OflC1DI5Uf6zH8XbT5583fPq2f/zG2/qKt6KcDtlReATcGWZCk68l@Cnooz1rlfsdQyoXI3N6a8dC/zPN5ha3yn@l@8dvopNYnVN@dyF5yT2KlYoxbgTHPCWDd5OY/XYNkYrXMbmSq1WA2fxv/xbSF//GOBgyHwbbvV8AKswj9WlGiW5iNUL4FA1DfL9v7/xjUgJOZuokRgXXHdZAy4xV9TEnRZcW3RtC2jlUMooShDPngwnhsPU0h31Dr6Y8AIP20Bz8cakGcPPabPDu4w9baRSqZbcluCSn9MkkaKqWlNV7wA7kD7cqtWkLcbtOGaz@TtoizpJU1oDB0ZM487n/xBXbJVn9ecG91SIFTbuvrhfr0OdsvXsVj1Fl9@RqE8VS6Lj3BVZmr2IgwrSaL14xLjx2bqYKWliOp2@26b3GeJKmoWUhBe/x2KhD3ZZdtVvKQlE8X1j7x8vto/Xn/9vf/79P/8e/X2ffv8BzUDaPbOvbEGkU@gSdbjuVirdel2su@J5E9/rQEeZSqlSUtqXzcQWcKDWU6ZmPrqI57PxI/6pa5WxZpJSw0XZ1v3s8b0eW3jXuU896ucH8MjkwfxakGMJa@QOsXYtHgyt/oZZqXFab0koENWkhlrItySeqh5cZda4C80kasWy2Kpree2Q3W3P@MWGmx5zYqAZFgI8@uWtL@pWD0MWb/WoV6weJKsv4rxvvLC8QqzRUFoGDQiBH7u7UdkoVQoVTWnX119AmtFXimoYxhMvdhoLL47Z2AKhsZA0r/oFTRG@sICC2fvEA8noXZgvtVK2oIpV36W1mVgFItGykjZoixlVDHsbzu/DtQF/9A9X@Ir3DfLxvSnK9WuDVdQtLavkPyzsazi@3nJFyyrAOMG6nU7ndbcDUoeud/Surk70qT7T5/qkM@3MOpPutMuwyyzP6GedvFNyZowToCzFsnl1M3aHiPpNY4M95VyoxVLB1Uzdej2T5bbvJIeDP0lyZjEh9g9w1VVNZVswPmXgBkIZOUFnxj9VFVgMBK3z1putxpst6KD11DYxx1Zd8ksJD7l9t5WSLi8b4K5W/f/teuis0sVdULnWZSq1/bwO0sfzeiMFIJ/7IGWJEVC5XW9tU0iYmZ@bH7zdAvlFSm03tmvOHv1k6iBSPOfEC87dFgDeXirs3bspGVx3AUB9E/pjMpXalKQNHBsb/lgBkVv1VFArLEMCpIXz85/zB4oe9OLL7cv6ZWP78nJ7G/636X7pP8H3cvvaPz0W15o4i/AWspZmQ6k3labPLFrwLit19JGVJjjq8IR4jaxWajXQAZfc@m/zX04v7qEPFrklQ6mF2BbbiqFRwmxsS4i9ePvV/4K/5tuvfh/lRQZ/RkWInWO3VrZQ2yxzpRNuzH5ss8f8ssGNv@AVfdDjcR09bX6zcUFKUV7IrMLn/BNqqZCUcQBuO/022jmQ2QuIeo33MVErFcR2Sp1rLLYtForE7n7h2hWPx//RC61cjPOJGjyo/8LzvMeRUi7KCZGrWkaV1Is6t0XPPxvyC6uuf/QL6y4hdlFmRgXw0/UYx4wQA0KKKYokwYhV3x7hVm5cK5FQLT2tfSE925VwHkWf0EpYl88R1A72a@VynS/zbD6hbrN1fwvuKvzvb0A9WLMPcZv9WncEEnCzn81rTbRcHpM6r/Dv0Wv8Y8dd/Hv6Cv/Y8Wv8ezrBP/a4g3/Hr/Bvt4N/xyP8u/cK/x6/xr9nA/xrfi2bVavi5jmhJqWW1cvNmUgoqsZ26s2vTdx5xTLshtlr@R/lyebKLBlrfs2Y4afZK9yzH//pd7/5zXitFpfi9KmTnOq4TE1WAftQIy9evRsXYjW2qW6qGSvTzagdtQMOk2VclhlmhmoPFJW2yjIGy8wzc5YZOWoPXAb8ZcBlZvosM2AZO2NDRAgF16SdmaCrD48B/PUBkAt/Ju5M7KiZLoOMLBTa6CuJCB5cF@2m0GBxJr4wQNeUVTkjF8wWflumIb540VS2Wlq5xGQkKrndeNGMt8SmiPbGtXKOdebGRvOFCENzRuTEhz4s5nmgwFZjSrOpcDQBBgiLl5ft9v6n99ttBYeh5mPncPF/eDiKvt74Pzp0Hh86Iwf@Dw8PoesY9dTdFDDou3drwLD9x06sXt1pVojtB6w/pmzvNOtZCd2FFHBzDf1S73ktIMKzvtEU4mcJ1D3OUP2ofn5WPa2S@yx4BUe7uogQROMO/wnXGQxxgTpyBtfpGTroDZ1nnzdDF3con5@B1@cM9K7wHxS86Ot/hX/zv63/x89YkiUarWTi/HI7QVcS/5LJ88vzS/9eTyYS/ktiG/7QA94xyfllHZ0U6RxcjUSylby85H5wTyS3OcA6ZLNdp7SLeDAsxMIsKVt@S/zXfULW/tWMV0Hu5bp1PkP9KCZWmb7YV9NszjKZZLUTfEoBV4n1C9q8kKzSd/Q2Ow219ac/os9l7CQpUj5XrapbjL9oOa1azQVvxVK1WgpeNhOJ8vWrntlRC6B/5HLJZLUKLzsB2Ay8QtoGe5NiNdaEe@vOHZ5JSbu4CGBmc4VURs1g6iCnPGRreHrXZ7jnB4f0pQlgNfkYfuKFs5JEhr5Tg99Ci4sV8c6dhP@N9Z3d5J07WjlzcRH6jMfgpS55tds902230T97cSG2RdoHU87De6Z0caFmyik1nnTcxKf4ET3IKiGp7EOtTrmWgY1ruSIE@wXIb28XcvV6IQc@hVI8iWvqDSx@C8obF@NVMXZOdVBLRc4BxSp6R/cHQV/GQYGdX8aoQVkun0wAI02CDHgZwz8XeS4fbvL5JGDmUuQx1XKZR02yXCFRSpX9v9oGaOUg5PA/lNSyqdxWcesuyLz4581WXciTq@dGTb2snRsVnFW/rHb9zxGjtQbjzp1sGVBUylSbQrt9f/d4t92uiaKIghLc0JO4u4BGLNx4g2qeL7c4RirVu9TMainPoD15HCkOIwQrAdIVbSuvlhBJgtlHYyyAEoFrSxtsQ9DoiTehzDG3AZ6gzkDmPbhYj3XYAC82QOWNmcyii1mMh9O92w0jOfzyQ8NXSkv6XeBjhJfg98IsJ1EYxJ882t3bP05r2xKLaQ9299La0bN7MRVf84t3Cs7i@9P93fuHzyDBk0f7u0f7Hx18tv/sCfh77GxxBUzfvy@eUdeK9zP2ufDSfa0bhm5MDaN9Np2evWIvTbNtQmNaU6iUM3CZZ7ShLmN9Ua8q/Lqmp798qbtjutjbH3777Q//u7e/8923v/Ptt7/z/Z9@9f1vw@/H8Psuf37335TzeP/pV//sd9/@9u@A53@A3x/B7yc//eo3vsF/9P7H8PtPEb8/9n@RePwnAKxf@elX3/vRT7/61R/A71/6vx9c//3aT1b/vv@t9T9M973fvTnOd/8t/H6Pwwrifve3uR8@r8X/bR7vV3/w9l/8O/7/p/4fOn/n7b/4Y7z5L//0B3/6n95@899rWulP//Xbb33v7be@@fZb33n7rX@svf2Nf61morffffv9P/irP/y9v/rD/5H@f0z333uX/7c/@Kd/8b/@xf/@F3/o/34Cv38Hrp/8xb@HrvK3f/BD/P/eH/ztH/0Q///nf/W3f/Drf/sr/xM5fpM7/p9/@W/4/a9/7T/@zW99569@8o2/@fWf/M1v/sFf/R@/@n/9xn/86//@9//6n3wTPX/zJ3/1R7/yl9/89l9@65//5Te/WnP/9o33r97B/6t/AJ93L@e7wHmXer2vz1c/V3n@PthY5AJ0AtT9y29/45eAwP8FY2@//WM85wS/Nf8/1lSK82P@9v8Bh3a9zhiSARf8fv3tt7@LKPofAEXwH@LrO@HLUgh/@c7iBdD6WysS/fJPv/rnP6K3mFGp06oNjt0lrZTaAv1mq1z2x29/QQeS/NIytBCAn9N3kEMthX0HedvbH37j7Y/@8dsf/ubbH/4KDt5SrpzeTUvqLathEDH/DvEwYuFd4mHELzD/FE2xSakv4I194Qd@8cUXQvtCwQN1dy/A9wvy4hfjQXjgzg8KwtAfT@CxCxZ1@86M79z0fcOcGWu8eNHC9Vbww9xTJHtsBaJRPstmKb9gM8aXddAfIs22yDnDO/li8EzA2@J/4ZwJLDXzp3vhmVo4yeGn87PgTiEP2aRm4WISyWqMS0db3IfWiSnfXJlhDWaz1AyUYHBADikIugfieK2WwoQ1Xh545UWrlxgVJZWqQb0xNU@TbpcQxOweQYGUtdRT1t6qzXjCFMKrB@hICej1VFQ1MVWq3YcMa7P7DGEhcAL74kWtXqrN6gjuDcdHapa6R2VCYLXUrP4G3msEE9IJsftvoCilWipVL2GGWEnePOk2b6Q8VY7qnmIpvw3gidv9d@4y9qGolkS@SLCBCOOx8Z5axMaIEB3Cm6ktvzr0Hzjpt0UI36Cs/FwYD98h2XSHi6sYAeBKkizLDH64/r7D7kLwjINKUbbwSHEIKaIIooDQg@H8UEpIUfum6AXyj9W23vtCYFiZzc1NIVYXs@KhTKhTFOaeVOjsA24HRPWiwsRCWURvgw6CBGWB9FXKfzOOC2txxgGzD1P8d/fuFvsQqknPhZ/ApFTWyTkxDmU7lRI1gF93UsJzUEsEoFMCdCHIsxot5KWEdJoxuRbDMHZ4eOgXgjye14QUkLmWVfEdl5Om02kMUshyWk6n/adMT/KQfYdMof5T3kTk0lemmablqqA9VRl6saiqo4IKjJ5v3ryBVqH9VZUDUD6Zv9VKy5UoEDy4XRHLmgcHhrRcWeCaOVMLOcYSNMUKV5IlBZZgW0mB78rnhQiuRFwrleIUD7AvJ7aCnXcFlcgBp1djdSxocHGVsJRPBoF7h2zv8PHj/U@Px60WEwz6arbRHrtO1/C8BIbtfnqfn8jQyoVkrNFA0McVDRmMsF/JEDM@uP/04KjCeKX9JkhQwaq0rupXs6wKsfH48@2Yv/NIxA@/OeIR3iuLuiW0chaSxupCrGugZoEL5qgAV1lVeOwN7jkz0OnTophWC6jZJWlSmQm/6EwZmiXlNkygT@E5DXl7mzAg1M8lWrpAJ7RWQajX/T17TBXqR/vHkOD4kKlaRhbqX7CZjBlKl0LdqlmGPZgMN3Hzm9jMiJE6bTYyafzTslm4q7lCWs0XWxsb1rmEeTap2c5xF@MlvJ5LWI0P4GLCBwL7ALzggjxwayLz94UeHFb9zXloACzBd@iJah66WVLAeWwOThhHrypQ9/JCkBDb@PLLCavXQb@WDh4IMeAWQxbsT5PMnjyUqZl7U9eg0AFjPfMzE7/oJ/dMb2zpc@g6gI3Y5eVlHyAdPGBaXaNXnqKH98su@XTAfTnThZhdqdTeqLmioJ1UKm@ymiaAh7Cl4Aa4DSAA2kewpfC/qgeZZLMlBTiVKorwyGazAs4dC0LFEBjtFXmTqdUkToPZnEpbRQT8SIQ@q2nh5cedfbiIm83wuBgCAWwwcVkmCCvyMP@tINAbIA13x9Eniat@58zcuZPFSYxsLhPOVlCN2SW0zWY2l0WMC///hQew@GrO9riezajbyhicOjhz24oOzg4489tKB5wmOMvbignOaT2rZraVaV1gwjY3AcrQwkhNnBgztDjM/cS6Z1h9Gc8W1UTKQBO3fZPa9SBhvVfrOV36nni1J5v4XXc8D8wT5HJi1bHROF0NzVTQCWqWSJ4Lg9oZnVoWjNpARnsnrq1bQk/uOL257E3mFp7SsRy3FgdxMB4ELKAbIIfg3NdONpurNFhLHjvjHUHLF1MNNQMDCP7UUlpLbxg7xWKlJ3ctQ3d38pV8Kd3DA0D@EtdOPlMZyF88fvRwMhk/NehU0E6uDAnQQhja8tkpVfL5VqMhiqkGZdPCryFz9iRtbECfNvSeBE9cAPMkrdSCxD3TrdXi8Z2sqklqJZspXQoLxCHOsYZ1AZOmsGZpxPu5zwEqtmMDs6mk9bR5Tlio9Pv9y63z1OJF0M8l/gb4uZT0dOc8fK1KkXgVNk1L5iIQfPQ@oPvcX9uriFq@JFYb1cV7sSBWW5fC3ZHRM3U8DNTMnF9PVQCmzKHGIKMmEy4rruNMKh2j77jGImJWLQQReYGuR8iJl2F2zQzmeH49u0Ik0uz8OpRcXrwMUwXFEi4vAe8c2YB2375rnTbNNtRyrrUPLAjIZzsw/YrRYs@fC7Gtp59l63Vo6vNcUcvlc3ktWyjkixqMN@VcIV@CzpYpZPKaBlBy5VK5eAl0rShvYvRlN7Z3HtB7hWzbJ/QKN87YaLHkm09N67yUlXg5Esnq5WXsjRD78OlnGgyQa68EDLqfaVK9ls2XwZVFl5aFAjNB0yQtK2VVSc3i/y0ODf/fPb4G/xreIVVWE47RYsunMGzCUG@zR2j5YeKwYwe//TNg94zumhh7Q512NO@5juf9PeLc0@0THnTf5GZSw6CHOn4AzRuZk@GaGM/GIzT2Yrj/YBD2Rx0oILJDHuEe3FzLcVZFKLJnT9bU8nFomByQwS2TQ/SnBx89PI48j/d39x4KBXbv8NP7Vx55P1KePdp/cBy@FnlokDQfgvjF/UePrr76j9zhs6f9qePiT3hw@Cy3uIVeeGBWyMG1HCn0JiD@DV9JsASJAhSxfDFwqAIes7gDyvEd35kvLJwZdH7OTwObXrjtnx8MrwjHwRFhnSGn7Risy236oLZO9vZ8WV4tlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlo5fc@9vgOdQx@OOBgq0loWUiFmfOa7VOzN7xobwGE9WllX8cjYWQngIQEbTLtlqAGEGrbf28DvruCzVsaYGm47ZWk94oBc6XXMwhDH4zAkiCB1dZ/B73wvSG9FrcrPHhOdBftdCrOvRhZgginui@FCf6LFS1ctUKnfuqE9csZwVx4BIb2Dsz4Bi2TPoQbo7T5fEiSw@YO0BLmpYzjgG@kcDpPWy1mjt5LR6KZP/69/68d/9ya/X1K1mZi@zvfP4Ub4CLA2kV0YCqi/EyqTOaOVSvlTOaqV0qVzK5dVCPp9WtTRogsUyKAMZtaQWSvmymi7lyiB95MoQmi8XfRFYCWReZasCYO0ufsF5mzQieQiqD19@ZK8TepLF9PB9ykQD0ogCKp8TOjK@ZdZg4GRqhmWLDCDqrMtiDx7sZR48EMV7@ILbN/YyotjDl3wpkyneE0WDQvZKKEmJDk9TQlt44oS/ZDL3ALtTDgDNyIviEF/2CziNJoomvuztPniA@fTxRcP0EO2Eh/AXK3gpQjQbX0AyJwCvQmgQbZfnk6OC7uMLZokhD3jIHoSJ4kdBcTDkKY/GATwMarq7K4oH/GV3F0P2qNp5XtBP8GWXLlF04QVIXhQH4Bi40NlEsQNOJHxR7IKrO9fBD7@WjZbG7YkuinOOHkSQKM4ott49EcV24I/ZfOaXJo/YrdCLymt9l17K@CeKWlBojJYNX7KimAtfclC3hw8/04eTnjHg19zlzy7U9OHDrG7OpvsPOh991BkMOu58d/@jpxi0t/cQpJD51O0MOn7CThsuB1LtPdT0k9H86gW1Pmi3K7q1MuiTdjun21eC2vO2gSWEVK@gZP41wIxG7T0I2nvYvquvWj4mgG3s8yN4dvC6N4LnPb3Dg4KLgug563TEKpK/ojQTAuoJuPCL3fEEeKidHuld16ni@6zGMmkUVeaNQqZVpQA2Ank/U73E8H4C7zrO@STP541ZLdOqzWpFje8/6ifE5kzLm2J6Y7SjlvOVDX1H1XKpWQWtVjj9OItL6g5LqHe2XrPEp8kdDWR/sbmzI4kNtbWjqaVKofh8ayqKyQred7LFyutEJp5hDG/JRrG1U8xHUhSLKV3RKsUiSGCAkwkM5B2cimknEmeGfpJMYmlpYgCqQHVlc6qnWe0nZulZjZeLzZPVWU2tcgu7LHMNWA/NuU@7E8flIAcAbraTqeDKe0JUyyURCqAoiWQyZHqgpwuLrZ@ff/345Pj4CxL16v6cxRP@/fmq//rRwz354DB4Q0Ps8gOUQB1X3kOutRTCRdHA6xh0D/khDJ6gxwV@eDrQdSx5n3bMgRgbBASmhWTfKKp8/HAJztHQOeM5o3GFKlnWs7sGQzv1Zo/ptTq49B5LUKmYnjyjYbtdr9fatRHZH4AqBqk@YWTEfQHmwONlD00@UPJzPDHnB7RrmctqpzaLzQBOu8Yk9cXI6b3QUt1qD83T36vdw8TVNjw7VaNmuK7jiqBFi9X@jl2b2p7eN54YLhozOTjcBCECj9El@sxIbrLmPsbeQw3lUqq7zF6U7NPpKKFL9U5y2Qvn40IPRE7i60Glz@lkJ@7NuKz2ayzxHKK@gnd3kyV68r3kTq4KeLrH2knwyrzov@gzjRVyVdIwEggLuhLhB@uts2St/gk8OOyTSgVK4zf0CUDFzACw2aMAiD02L6vdmsUSEpuxJCEpVx3UGpj8Am/bkii2JKlx0RLqkvS5UIf@Wp3H9Jo37dCXTVimo2qZQnUGfmoxVx1C8@rPZ1W3Np66RtWCV38ajx9i1auAVMAdgHl9kXj7S99Ibkv5GverEqgLCwSOttyuzao22koEwqhlaxCQauQyadDd4VZMw5ivFdJqIZ1N59JSEX1hwE/n0@AJug1IFwkrITImpjOzjKymVUNNJzIvzN6LZPokASILIY0l0xNn356OGPhAUyFt0is8AT0pbcsCnavnMH1bImIFllHFigHWh2xspocI6qmhW5QimZRYdithbSYwzubxdLzfaFUq@7Px1yEoIb3aKaSKmdTrZLKa2EjWPOOVUK8KdWQvVOvxBlCuP8PJvOmoAa0MLrWoVRqNDlaxmElnM1mondm@GGyLdbGVzmwUVGiiS0Zsg3G@EZ30Q4ln4Tduo8xtGdB0almrCjLNwGVLmlRW8lv5DJ8F5CmFsc/eEJMs0RSDA9uJeLyoxePJeBXXHzZEf8IZeBrxszhw1/gddUcEYUysiGUNIyxYI53JzQSlA3HsUsBpD5YDlfZcuDy/3K4LXxOO8KTltvYc/4rPH@8e4t/XwKsMr6Xnj58dPjt8IDCFtnjK7Vh1oypX21V4keT6XSFWYQw4adO3JqVsMPa@m0dT2/Xn/NnEUwMAVyD7xw3Wok1dhon6GvsMLRXssDjUQXdHDU3LthpaEcY@4KZBVE1Tq7g6E8NzCXIdGsM7h/Jtp@p4yO8TNp/rKSlQ8u8wNkhtCoSe2NUZgN3a7uDpbrAvbXdv9TzB5kzBqekmSOq4jy12Ho/FL@FPiN2lI4caP3LIYuGhQ1xR9RdDsrkCS5aDtYqvxe/G4vE4LgpUmPcmRu0WHOL65IUGJBOzncADdCWcx4IhLZ/HmfOY8mLsfamVso8PDu377gODnxbSSrm2WI@xjCrh0ahqxffNi@2NExUoJitmT9IxdjdG2@rFckkTNe5RjbETKa5W0mlo5ObGxYaDayIs3Kn3xv7464yN49lcnLFmLTar5fwt4Gq9LqnbGppoK7IKjAB9tSBlLuqcxusUUNAg5O0v/SA32y7Bu5ZR4V3T8imtXle3NJaMjd9@9ftobed8/7PdRyyOM@l/9yc/0op/9yf/ijabxS9pdl3LFmMQE51qoRg7Px@fn1/CxcPysVaMFypXTIKbr/Sosbqialnbtqusouj6VjGV0@7aVcWPqxbVZMyTYv6aVTEf8y78IC1TgqBgUYm8xAK2QGz/qZnX1LvbO1CdnWxOq25A@6vhkVMW/m0bXhlat/T4xQVj8NKt9wYDUyOXorDKG4ltv5G22Rtc0HkjbbAXtTpuDFDxoGqw4LGFB/dw0S9eTylbcQYKEqs3LquXrRStmIAC@dwwtuzmFYJtbuDJjWWvLRv@jC2P/jBR4OHBa/BmbL30xMRWUlF6PfF6R9g2WL4O9LGlLI7Tsq1gHYT/SVIz@faXfkPTCn/3J7920b5of6GBklkuF1Qt9rOfbU/tqWf06j8DADcYVgkURZIV0QIKOkIFk3H7iaafKnTIXdBtpzYK0zx@oG6igslAEDEHttEjdVM4ReGJmrbNbfv1EhRtC@0upEkYJ1tayaogBFIrF7bdQTdNMNgWGv1stJLCufABBsHYzEBgrwofLECBxwhGY6fb9qypO6aTLwlKp7bS7A4kgRw@QLOJG2QvwmfsEnA4Zet6Ul5kj7BGghYbGZ6HRhhhTBI@gCS@ZWRrzsY6mjbBmKYNI4mMUaicFNBrQN4tyNviCdrkm6Da8whpxkvHE9kgkAsfgGxBWDBB5GDmNkSoAl/6ABAAdUj4gM0W22bZJDs3U6nqwsLjJe7RR5uVemBWQcBkCK2HZjyCxFWMB16gCOC3OJEu/BYGiS/iGQDhMPiSfg1UCUxObyjFkd2TdwYFsMjGWIKqxu7cWZSqVjN7SUY1Qvgn5hgnwKgd7NVlBWCBGvZhryKmGdrOrAa@IdkBxlNUXKA6iRvNrEaSMhFfLwUB/t@ZaJEirzQVBVSxAn578V7RBZRBYkQ7b8Mu264xVSsmWVj4LpS9S4Wiw@2hbtmcfShrXwSBl1DCn8WCL90A0zqOTir6dHvVrgYDyXuKnxlB62qcGfj2MLj9NGR@B5MgdZgKqmJaFLtvuqD10F6DwHRjIqsmMdnC1CWVg3bRazmGm9nzSXxQKozN4KmjCUI/nw0yndR1oEG9sWOTzUKyqYQnCYAigEf55t54saf2GX6Wym8bShwtkUem3pDyscRkg5G@501pcbG/44J2HOAmzYyBzLqjHtPKLEGERmbp7BBckhJRgTsgPCOOO5YxgiIdGQYdP/MqijIAgWraIdt8j02gq@EDE0Yg21P8T6crZ@aJqRyjfVjJ6eMpNW7pJIYyGHY/vq/At4NnOc4Js8wTg88VJ5bsxHgM1AeQgNOA2cUPEFvBDStaNo2zGGqax4JfER5F7iylI2k3EvPk9WdW3Ui0sUUvaLwxXfws@qluR/BL14Xg683e3AssTZG9JHiXQ5Zr@DZmanG0HhEaTxJ8m1k1Mtck4xrEOCHGxMDWFDqFsWucMtSABRxjgGl2A6st2Iuhth/QAEB9D3oWmqCcuBW0NQQlcXuJLnQ9n8Hb7EOW1QSMyA2B@Ua7AAY2fW0ZOoRBUqyHN@lBw8g08Y58BXrnqAdhaOXCJz9MH1A3usk86IK82YYPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wdSM9U9Q0ILEAJV5RkIyGmAGxKTIocdJj@anJO7QLxkgq7DinNEIKPaoBCooKOLIe@Yr/4fpQAAfd0j39kwDdQeXZ2JpPV1KlryoaH31TyHFu3lPHABJHaUSbGaOx/vdbEr5b7cBcuiX9KTR4PxzszFGZr5Ttz/hSEvlfzt/0k4n0vjoPjKX4yaDAiC2to2swjgnpg0ufGugl/FxKnP62VPg/or4L0J5XilwiEMQQzS8/T3TQAS3e6J@n@Wa/qB5xShwTg0IpG4Im2jN3gZeQFLnPcD2M4E@SjYVDHOqGVXIAk8uneRda8hkHMefDqv4/NGSSyjTO267r6PEHhSYyNBJyYk9jD5jDsUwg4YZhh59ywrjlrzFtLyWdhchjUwn0MLppPE85vBsqtLGP4jIfPIHzGw2eLTINsG7MWF8nQ6xKrg1SPVjeDmAhmHsS55BaJFyEEGeRxpnIQGHO@5HcJv26NUgf45m/QjrWAMIAmxoBwI6E0njcbzZbtGWdbrZQyAGIXCRHQ4gC60SKcnvVCN2LfOrXGjrfkZaOxVRiV/HKjV3foUwOnFaxj2EBEGBxfJtrHHIz8DRdcIPArDBBQDoNAFA12JwkzWQ2telMgEE5DXOCYF6zhF6ZF0pcf5PuBuMRRzxEbBdSKAEL/sEpQTAhhQc/hX9ALuMPnrgNxgrgSffRrhHba4q04YPJKV@G8pkqNFCmVJAXFBLSjuFq7WpUgHJqicSUoUs1Lv/2jxd947@L3oV@sLj0RLB8wqkK0q@AeRxAh/O5CWGX1WqRdoQTKlm4ZLoxc@1w@9UdryGZLCdQMng9WwTszJ91hItL43SRvHzpJKdpiJSSFea0GVZzXeLfk/SJAKUd4mMzzk80DQvDTcwYCMDIrkxl@slk02axW44yDzdYkO4sUckaFnPEkPPZsTSFbfjLQng6C4QWbpwXSKW7CFAGeyodREIPGIvP0UwOXxV@iDUlcYvDzXPAcogKfhlDERjrrtlbm3ogUOsK0rgBAQrwGoMc/xlsRrjI8VQrfQh7FURnwKP7mkwHnFUBgxIKr3M5yIiQy0oFB4BdTNA5A3xVTDUFUaZoY/zL8J6YDz@CnXvfMLMdUlz0z6St//yCeLcRspINGpA81k0OGjJrMM9s3UBqVOWL43fqhA1Jd58xhiRXCNvgrUz@p0rGcjjLScXsLfqKT@8rjeTLQH3Chhd0dOxN94uRyFa40mUR2q/LnOoM5sB38sk/E1jrIej3H8Oz4BBq16wxs0zPSDM1gnhi@2mH4H4sQonKy73Q8QfA3WnE1FkFzukJRt93Gj4a32wncv5ishJuxaTsjkmc8LqD@C65IemBPPtDDccLpvDS6k@TtMPHDAX6yY7N7kjgc@4E4b7rLgId1Qf6H0CFIMMxzFpojGSVHUbozSdAHMobOyBmA1Df1ZAFTXwF/sICNBdLHYypLmumo0lYin4@gXpLopvWkn/ST907KPtESejJMry0DWEJGmrlXcYyYdVdk116bHU8W5Hf0/uU9ipb36ObykhZ@tcxcNa/xwPfLOptYQICIi2Jkby8GVh34Vu9acZaKEnqjXMUTvHMRe7R9rIcl3YWou350uQ/0kQ7fPHgLC/7ZOvzf3IBB8v13bT4duj07mgO/GeFOzAR9jM0L1ksTEP0gibznenYhad9/x7wgLn4H8wGKECDGEuOy0Z4ydMwxqN1eOIEcAL6F5nHH1jW6p21cNR64okzuaZqdaOub6H67Z1j63Ogl/JjpCNygxk9BYSN@9W4VR0ZHTM/hul4Cxq5kGArDOCKdR6qsIRk9fZpMricrHsUMqYdmyqmEB@vxh@HXWDNO8dX4bDXoAfF4DKdjT02c/hzPx3Nust/iX@Ly@Sgff3hLojWI2xECeOCjp5peZJu8iX0@TYRVeocRIYwrL1cZLWoHENHI0vU2fD8U3V5TaNxIolrQysLyx2pWt7h5U4tHqCKgSb7u9G4keRvRvTPNRUiNA1uwsL33G0KuQcZNHt1uIgqR@9zYYo59jSegH83T2WtGlfYKhhqmJE43MUndJvkiKaBmfABPnHD6DJ4IcGBM2pyggrrhnJb/cUtGISN9HJFafB8Q0gFKBIsc5X4xIrGEwA3Rzy/DPLtr8@xey7O7lGfYA5azjEQSuktZ@q2AzXNTE1hGf7KGO2MQ6s7wuIltw2U7uouzFedxM14x0yx@Gq8AQ44b8cp@AphyvBev3CeHF68ckeMkXvkEHIu@Fb@IV4JugRFceCXHXfT3WTi@d@OVvUTyUpjoJ/9vd9@21kaypHuNniIt4UZlSiUJG4wRwhYgbK2FwcPBbm@g1YVUArV1apU4qG33NzMX@wX23M8j7FeZd5ir/RRrxx@RWZUlCYy7195rvumvjaSqzMjIyMjIyMw4BKFp11tYi8aUyryUn0wRIgX6TVojrth6fd3N0TCghY2VSleBY0IX2yc@h3H5X4H@l/RTnJgGL3HG@YQLq0VVTCwa1ooh7dCyYRIfzJjJa3o1r@7vsJFUVATNLNIez67D4EkNzywkhZEghrd8o0GfhCDk5tpsjJS1kj0QHd06cSgPcrJ9pp7H@kAzy@9PqPBZ3AjnHNP1zXglQcgAPgxPVL4Lzyl0THOMEe5knRlogag/L9zTKYx1Ehc9@vYI8Vl3shBhmzNFZJQYrCXTSYfjyzk0NugPkkzCb2GE37br8KGcTEpw70Q1lgp6Zt7xmh/rnkEw2JPfua87Vj2glhBBeHlSOJNZFq0LLIvxKpZ1lqYqk49QsGQOzfCg8YnzuW3rr1xOxI3La8Vdy5CpK02y5EqKSarsIbrVlT@S1qPNaxUxr75v@2pq3uKsJQsAVs2oFZGv/e/Q3/uivxuF2hBhooFZivXspXRavb53lZ3AvBM3Oz2AeOmqbWemchS1EJOcdgeWZn4fr02p@DD5ECVfGo2gT2j7hmzRnuAbdJvcWwgsaAnD6@TDT0v08NPS3YSa1kg6155RWjy0pOFIxyNM467dj6t0fNYQ4w2fb/ud7x7gYXKA7cEDPO7AcILkMsuHVz22connNolteQKRWlxTIsj5ujQa5vghiXu@uo2ubenBfv1ge39v9yMtus@fP3f0Gj2O8cOsxVlrtI4LZLa4jtaDGduWJRdJl3DZjeP48LI/HD067aWnZIkIa1IGfGrFsJ@e446WZZY8n5i7VE/KWhTVsD7F08BPSCWoOj6W7Lam64gIEoyyT3wNxKi3RG@Xd2sOpxeq13t@N6jXefkyiXn1KoahMTfizt8yj/JX4ZAT0EpurJtUisNMqO199eFN5UgdvamqneOtv6qP@8fqQ2XvCBEG3h1v7ta2FP2r7h1WVSphWYk8gthQEl23g0aA5LBqqVB4phjyVn8wFrmT3XLk@aHfVW/6jQDXVOuh3311KT@8XjDakFpV2o6OcYbZ5ryR3fYI9hac6JC2sVBumuw4CBcBRWXPaU/bxZ6322@2W20qm8Led9AOQuNrpjptGkGSt8bd2hUlCTkN2XSIc5XCAuuGqvtUHnc3BMYX@yuQGCUkCWLTU5pw0X/fTcGj6sHbQ4VgFVv7e9u1o9r@3qHa2T@gn@8@1vZeEz1rh0cHtc1jvOKCb/e3azu1rQo/EAQKnkIUiV@uwtG9KHgozlRpfMLNtzeg4Y9@JU@9ocGrG59dKEO1cNWD9Gn7nfZvQXOhlLoKob7AbZOvClR2vnLw@j2t@Sr4FTec5iqY7Q/SxyHn2ZwvqHVujSbLBs23kp6utOzlig7fR3THCql2ghJHl8jyd1cZ4GzE02wHKr0FGxWcfUsQCp7LBjQ19IhgA5QxWCkrTpG1sOCuM8gNaq3R6SNiqLQmRoT6B6q@MqYmpRRTTNvKACicIGo9nAcVS9ED4nt6sKSbHQ2lgHoaPZAC6pk8gCpag@2IWtYlrkb7VxDPakUe/NId7PC1sHoePdj0eRe7qnGSceMh9VWUYhAhOTqcCE1OeThZK2ft5iohl0eSsE5HJkYg6SlJJspVItu2Uck0CZsWrhq02ZtkfcZb4gbYCfmtUaiyZcdTRzAOCnptSUF30fF7YgIVm@4w76lVRD8qaw/tdpS6jd1KBn1mQKSNTOIR1dvWWmHw0HpUc3OqRV/bSHL6VGOC9i0ENqcQ@CNgCFAusdNp8ErFXq0A029pVs6GfeJInNv@bpcndm5eNYJEBW21lf2l/dtvjiaym9gnGTtFxo6G6LdgSGolX2W2@kOa4yxWOdkVpGDjsj8YtWUMs8ke8I0TL3NUGgsbtfZzeSPRGugw2WKv37MaPScuvqPVc2LKh7TKHC9355H4irMgE@fTIix2d0DHP@9fB9bdmYtLpJsAxy@kCPNdOQ4/xyPGRPTPVCw7fldInrpa3tjePM39/rOLDKoiFiSBsTE6xD9iTLRF04Pv@dhgcQi9S880k/kuvDpHbW2Dp6UlZrkBRvvAyzbt617VS9E7MTeefg6Xm8nn/PDLl7LUykEy6azX4WU2lm6uOjFNulznTGkTEEt2ErIk67PmicswI3n9Cm42GAWE8@lBjmDfPpFXTosQ07vzqxZJFp3eVw93BN9RG2xREedGh/uMPR75n7Kb5cUNJx8blCiLnFkjol0Dueg4llkKr1dT4LbvB0fy@@HgVu/FTpaH74K2fS@078Itt3g3LFmWLFgPB/v7PWBlcftDYKnv7t2AZZGchhZxesSc7nwmsqa9v8Wfp8aO5x6BwdqLE5QIqNXaVY@vqE387axUcGwwsUJ0eLRdPThQadmfUF2Se9gyNLUYBOxH6l1sbdvusbDzIqUp2ixHypN5krBoixya7pnMM4l3h6jQOoir6REJizjKd6t9K1JPryysQrD1PQtEQ7kkdp@NDApPNOCvtAckZONBszqYmtnNjCw@7dA2Atd0c0U3tm342cJa1m4kzR2ObUC2TZB/Ac@S2eP3QfTjNdOOKFiIgYQON0mTpvWG9gmH1PCACnpecgTvGRYzpDCyFwU7Y2gHw69CUsP@8wzFjCRKuOjClljXyrFGTfTjeaPmsEEilgEflp76pVg00wsj4vnJuj2gTrzoZZNLECmZSKP6yuYKqn72VS9hTI1onSxHCrk91@YZmxOD5RlOZzXs0t2FHsMWemVSPEw2RdL23qZyf5@mZJVItGRoPrMz5iVBXllefvot2JO9MNVzfxa2rCGT8nPUHdD@PgYZjkM@3ifOre255n3MAPeQTkzrzYSZqEiqzow1JdF3Xoxs/AgXORciZBC0HplpJ1t11O0EbrOhy4pkQ@ciU32wpnDUUZk1U9T/en9zEMjfbO/R97cnkw2FYDr4FVb5b/vDMIi98qy4L9Yj@MsnnwXDYY@LiT9TF1Cy7MZ0r7Mde9uJwav0Ci/5vs3uSUt7J4nZrWvOGrgRPl70kIwap3ulyeO9XLFkd3WntltVTziIZStxFpkeph1L9jxq9@5DgGUwn0tg@WAfvsfhGv0jHFwDksjE3nxZpo3zTdyYIqQ1n3BWI20WqmVrcXL0W2HD7yFSiJt@HKq0@wNV5FPY6v6OM@tkvVBK1CfkwkEvS7XcdM5Lc1V6hgNdQEqCkNHEc2vBgqeGsZSEe81FH/ZRuNgKbuX0jC0n/XxxtbDyIsW967kjt3vy4sx90iinFS2@fq8bXg1vmp8u@pfXLdVRg1/Obxvj335VavmZekptLf0gkYSLK@U8B299Tn9X1YsCc65G8CVHRUZyZE@yxiq1oOJ9eOmRcvgLb5rX4CExwaXqSddwIVzsRuXuycpZuVculLonvbMSnPxGi@XRYnExiwc/0CpKMkZu5k9GZ1hT7VPXoHetEK@Ts5Nq1xDFriH05K0/bPd3K3uvE6dxUABwBKZtvflAXRJRz8GaDb4nXi@4yepjMleBY1NQkFJz7BVUhDs8nyfjOKbZJsxoVFzSZsNb/jt2UnMF72ow6vMbE50RrKW@tL@k5owbU4FPFKjISdvEcIR/AcGJy2RxMSRPx2JFnSuKulaE76RjgThBTRaH6dN0Gj6FQFT7cp2cpUIv8BuXQAKZ179wNbW@znnYidVCj0/xYMrhD9lhonCGr7gAoY8B3zagCdbcQ3b7SFH38buIL/KEz6hG7CfDBvIp1hTxBubf6jP7N3H9dSKAEH5OdC5PH3FqzYsUSfEd5MMFhD5LbvxxzQC3ShmUOXQWsKW9cgycLcWZRmhWk4mez92AnEIr@k/3IFfkX1PdiMo7UpxJwvfU@lcIWvKQ8qsNfHTialmrWs5UM4UtUsx9kxo46aLt0duAptVYbQWdDiEttJiLyYGv7N@r21@M2g9P0OZZhLy8z029zyXee/JekIpLebTAx4XW7ELpzOe43FeVjou5U22VFSsvHo10wyOVJC5buq9s6I369XZceCMaSuHK6MV64kXOevPTjNGXN48SdSIGj96fyHvN30t65CMsE2VfJdvHZ0oPUMDGs9rWZIJLvV678zKlk3brN2CzNFFTKanOyRiVmVRl7YOpxQlpcDjn52m7UY6hLBaNxOE5k95Yf5X2tJLxMjuJhngxTk2sGXPEohK3uciEu2WHRWqHXz@yQDBMMJoyM3fDVB7rymMLLEo9Ms2KF@TUBKeuTU7xMvwiv@CPmexJ5Ey5zOyXc4L5rXRevJuTBGKh@yg9m0xJaQJ3EXmoO3XPKhK3PZ6EOFtI7FmnwFGbgfhgt3AM/iiSE7agMJJiiu7RG03puEDRsO9dQ4iXX1N/yz9JvfZJxx50gltVwTbDZy@sVMLBfRSEoxCxojiMTXg1GHRw68gK3w27UOtAI0vLuG6JIVoru5eqwbJHyrv4ph3SqZKn9gH5BgYi8Yvw6uICzmTwgO3fQLTixKU98lKV3lgONGjOPF0SN/NAIfgGC@BO@8JGQkZOZg8oHQ78RuClSEcLSftJSVdbbZ3ClM/T4TeCkGS0pK2lUv901W582nqN@9znxcLTokWya30dXPCePosdrIhI5sUSogouF5@lUtbdcEPuhnMA6KpdLPTviTeD66DXC1IVWjG4YEhKaxgMr4Oml0odBNElMOCClXEzCT/s/tWwIYc7pHT5xIzwEg5duQ4jDsMn1me5Lm7wXZmbwqVVfNtMQ33dboKAxuOk1cftMF9YIEyA0AOVusGIiPLEUUmU@O5Z48K6SxcHUUQNxDmx7iYiMvT6o3aDRoZPslIdAiXXIHFjveYEJtReo@PDOdibhQDcY2IKGATMVdJ9OKT0pfl34aB0x8wdu29GJk/Sr89zhaZ7MGyT9I0JzKPC1SzcaYCP3tQO1eH@ztGHykFV0fd3B/vva9vVbbX5ke@4cVHOcXnVm/1dki7Rbbrcmu/Tg3TlkGqm@UWqsvdRVX98d1A9PFT7B6r29t1ujaAR@IPK3lGteuiq2t7W7vE2374TBLW3f6R2a29rR1TsaN/lVk21VFxP7e@ot9WDrTf0s7JZ260dfeQWd2pHe2gMt/oV9a5ycFTbOt6tHKh3xwfv9g@rCh1LbdcOt3YrtbfVbY/apzZV9X1170gdvqns7k50dP/DXvVAsZGA1cvNKmFZ2aQtLFrifm7XDqpbR@hQ/G2LiEcI7rrq8F11q4Yv1R@r1J3KwUdXAz2s/tMxFaKXarvytvKaOpfKfoMqNC5bxwdVxE8CJQ6PNw@PakfHR1X1en9/m2l9WD14X9uqHpZUanf/kAl2fFh1FRIsctMEg6hF7@n75vFhjelW2zuiNeP4HewdHBrkD0QYwrJCVbeZwDCDQG@JSPsHHwEVdOABcNWHN1V6fgCaMrUqoAIsKraO7GLUIBHxyO6m2qu@3q29ru5tVfF6H2A@1A6rDg1Y7RAFajDI@EisQ40ec68xToSXfCVmTRnOdXk4VW1HVbbf14C5Lk0ccFjT3MJk23qjae4hfq91iNLu48zA79oHK63pR9cBIlZOn8jMPqOJIiZt7W9XaUXWwa7S8YtjWnVWJ0Ip2e9opYle0s9EyJpmcH51UW/3Wn34mEbV5OCjG164SBvkIOfKaeqe7Fn6fIUrZDL1@vtKnTa6h/W64z6kZgKNb9XQx@D3lXJ0H5GTATtvHPysrQnd1xOE2vhBX3SyoR4uIFBSqP@DmL753cBR@Xwz0NXgvA/A5ugolGuTS1ylkGhkZ0cki4mb5JMJ/t3W7MAVswa816jjnBSWkVyoH9Kf3pf4hywO1gOSznLclc9jE8totH8LTDPSCIdE4D86IkG7xU16YRB8usgW7Oaw5/cu@v1m1nFMHS47on3gRdb5RvXz4GKiem6yPiPL1846nUFo9t2swkT3z5pkSo@LN@SeZfGnPuIPx2AjMR9waspN8WG1PrTM/iDVYZHkKh3aAu4VPMjQ@d5Wfqx9wG6usPSsNPH8TfRc5hbsBRHblha8E653xh9vzqQATTCOxUEkaesIGfm8VcfYm0SFb6jgJQrdtJuw/KG1@jLgdZ1IQorsld@x28RqPGzf2tiTHH59UHm7ebyzQ6IT2D5bXX6@UkpFYbd@dOXzI9rh8LMcdWxA6zjpafzKmiVbpPjwTLGif8fszwycz6Mg4rmbQeOHiPMQ2W0kLZkgyNDdEJmTejDRSwegQ1pxAI5HKcOvM2emZoBsoqsOetP1b1nF90lXYh7QxiydMY/aLf4AdjT9zRSPOqQZSLMYB@QlzqXdBcu99I4xFeXNDQfuQREvbfhYwrhFNOCjLrafhXct/9K8bY1iKKaMmK887FyTkHg0iYUydhU9mdnvOM6IPgDm6GH05EfNb/T1ow5wx@Hu/HBUGR0SGXeimjinjg@jdadPNOQz5NdAUDXT0rrCKb@jkeK5p4@To8Ag1mxgVJAsBja@ScClKI7IZJNsAftqwVGfhVMRvANwSppj9W/i3Fnd0VBKJn6I/m2iUiiBFQU5EardRG2kTJGPURwLQ84Emf4UPRj@P5AmM@Cv046ToMfUsoIAPoiSDFVoRdtXJkr7xlw0WLcbMTXtRx9jMF/tgbmMOqZvb27Fv4ZIoEdnbB585LCHrewMAoDJcbBhz9/IJO3Sp63Tq7Sjq@OepNfoDrJKrxVmqZiCm1s5c1ntcs3dCn44ypGzJqvBXaqqXsnG7ZxnPW2ZJrby6nGYFnCOif@Rf8IHINGEZy69FKvVSc4q6Flm5IAOtWQtOM0oYhKppV/vvLV7oqwQmQnZr2@@DKEI9Abwme4nJxrpKzHPTUZc5JVYHXEUPAQZxzYZi48OWXfOhpidAHAeN/kwBLlIRjdYIDoCnUP1xdBU9jEbiqCR2OowjjMIcet4RFpeVm8i7PlkEhwaYX/ck/j2gZxqmRKeBPjQGNru8p56648J5c7Dui0sln9y2Hdhu4jG5FhC10felUa/PyTV0Ue/CUe3PXY89UEfOgS98Gqo4xfSetYe6hMJo/RTM1CbZPfOy4wElmfUwvYI3gpNj/mDu9QNYCEq4UlucysqS8xreHTDHDq2bxeLKrsev1knmnBYUibiulpRX75IKSGoDhkaMAXbYbS5YJtNbgf3DtH0u@kPP2HthwrUawbNKDKpBZLPAmWQaj2O8dgYSdcH/ZBPNGgocAISUaIoB2mRoSqt0c81O2m7pnQcHROxS7kn399OxKTGWooaihlXt07Mt5KjwQSVlnRo0ChYaHFpmVGZteH6eudmjKOFJq@tVfq0F4mUNVEiyo@N6ohvIjejbx/xTR/ylx@HmD30BHfcWgUFwtBZca86LecYP9gUfGgHw6Z9JkqaTNMf4PiNtz79HvOiOTrUYf8a/igMxrQDaOTbt3mGUc/@pX/Zq2/1O/5Fu9/2aZ@GqPC3IvHwdcxfMWAXw/5NyCmF@EXTKtQcx98lvoyEYcPv6F6yZIXmCkfBIGubKYyG48qlhIngk3MYAcbpTJm/B5Mx0qI6z5bjSqmk/ynb4xWd0p11nxZnVZYbfQDQAm5jwoJCfEhH7JhkOZ@Wpgqc31fAwvFc5ZTv3GGxl8D4BZGIr2ESGBtkpswS7E5gZ3YnxifNW7fJMQiHCLQUbAdIkxNm@bHrI0M0SZGXsBRYU8XVglVVblFuEYcQX8Z3k3vp@T8Ye0LgT6BffDqLW2YxAou4lom2FMp@RUcZJVzYPLDNMpolMUmx9kW7Z7kfck6K20moydfju6jBlj@kFOkwe1NciRmZpY0PMt9l6yRy6mMHi8qCWnA4bgdUkMooW7ibYYNv2c/y5MclrpycQTBtachZC@m7SNUgKiEH74R5rY2yxFT@9oxZWnroqE0QsDzL5MzKBZ1NG82FPVDasr7iWqs/JGGcnqCeNvVYCEf9wcIDqXen7JgZmW0WrRuO801DYGG2Mi2WT5pM2vIYX8el1CQ@E0yTpBhbmhEPYfvK3yM2nyTibbmO@Vauj79Bh7toFttNRYtKNN5NmftYFK9h0WsWmmhKMe4IUlqKnp/UqeP1uyWIhinbqzpLjDpERn0sXy1QE2SKqPRwCjH3adwn6NEkyqHdJtHOHp87iTppJGdCnppXiSCXoCcCt8Npk@TSoAXjC4SJEw03ElKRwnnrjvkqr5g7R5BhvBCA0IqDXHwOJSe48WBN8BFnB2hl67AWKkIS0bcN28IhCvofEYyj8uvDHW3xUB/nimclgXQbQaJdBZe6D5LxN6efJ/VbhjJFCpriM0gR9WhKNl0@vFd/ti9UjiBIbX6tLX0LLjrjqEXChv7Yr@q30IHjpnTNxIxKToQ6iwaaC7RLuegEsl2F9tceCsfDukFPI9pAyOMsPhZ1DYTzXilE1EaV2@YYRRxNbpltjsptSJWYoeQ3yK@noqi6vHElAIFgTPXLRYKAsKaMPS4FOPSOzXkJRPUYUcVyEdOSHnJU1NjOc8Z7EFUXeLZslSjMKvHChpGbCYQUi9llYkRIZ5ldJIZCC91MXKwSz2f3Jy5BCrHhfaE4DYUelSQNo5ETAnLy6YITS5STonILmoP55bNlJ/Ey4m9@@6JgvS1MviX6RBie5IqTb1cLibeJZpeWklUTNYkejt1q4iWRwrERjqTCn/uPXVPskOeRTai1yUhoGdo@G8nBaZdJ@zbvl1Cts1O20TEMPNsz3Gy/6pJiJRGU/f4A7GqBrwwQu/1P99ZYphpMdK4AjktnnF2ysiFkjTWNpR7dwk7XRNqLAhSYPW2/pd4f7ewkwr6ej42hUTcYLhcKBTDxuR383thW4yip3c8nS@dbV51OfnDzl@H78zzL/iDglABrZgcd0JDQpAi9/vBCMkMAByqK0jntyIq9/lWrZadgwA0lBo@GTUrqaAiKF6B2ZPTy/ogPgBikXmB/RgfRv59VNPtufFE0NRRzDUW1YRJ8nTa3Z0QePGjBPju6qWJgEMzGmonWLae88RkrCDKb8GBx@GLnc2yenH4TdDp9V31AUmJECpj7OllhZ8euUJAiuGFk796rkOPRuiq4bncsv2IUsXkd4MzCZPJMmLjwiI1/EFxUbwfZ9MlPaVpWqMuL6OYi4lO7Kn2RdnSw@AeAFT4ktB9UuusPsg2m02RhWur1DI6/EUZPi@7MvU@iiMNnYppm3y4Nos5G1@NgDdR1h3UBE8ueh5d7ckfxiLjp09tiCzQsCAyNE2KuPKwGXM3@cWLxetRqPUwqchoAGdjvkoiSCeXPCUS@A@AZqKcf0RNRtP@ao2m9MxFQRBQcJOuYljuoUEeFVOpxo/zrTbZSqaj5weKiqlQ26UsupyqbFbWNB5ubapt@b@L3D@Wl5eWSyNxt5zM93DQPv6pNgsEnnIuNy@E2/aR3ZfiNwVobQzyfL8@7pfl6eX2jFOZPKptw66dv//kv//M///V/5Sv6x7/jxyb/OPkpKuR5Xn6@8Xn@h68l/D7ZPluYPz@ZH5wtXJTAZX/jqOH92ijnx@aj3vA8lZFVwHrKdqRmn83RZ3RVZZICdv3hJ5IuayrTCPMZ/TSUzFEsYzONwHoewI/ynLbwJunA5FaekMgQ0DGO42l0GgEM8Gi9IUoSLrADlfpyt2IO7hEOJioQ3apkdCQe1lmvA/i0xJEU4ItLK1au3QuDHk7Ar1nnle6lUj59tkd1zb/5n96GF5v9W/XkNKueFNQTVz1Jp/mjuPKCnjrz@Ta8c6UYbQfSaZfexFcLMDNUYZsVPd4/cK6dCXKnUvOcsgeQTJgKLixecG60@2NnGUm4Fl6k5pCZU8kRCV8yoUrm83zvKw3LZyrxNZ1wtWFFoa53MdyYdaMSjS9UID8UQ4C45a4QZK1PTeKmjz2S8S1vnuixTnE2IQYMsh683uF5jwe0Fs33tM1zYi@FNEdsPi9PsTaWxBma0cYbaT9GgC9UZDtZYE/ChcxCSqy8rV5yN8UL2@6fZj6xdRgHI2ObLpV@VxYTiDW3Tbj5nvZr0Ybccr2i0u3oesVqKj1p@61SVpXuVWfUHmh3BW4dE@pz1NpXmUkYUQYkcCRm/9r0DOODAhMpamJYJFnWWDX76LrMhJ52TacBdjy5ObKIkP8pS3P7y8TcdvLsJWLYQXiAkYpM@Vp@uxPqqCtDJvaFPzxHdkC/xQnVRnJvxud5yLA6gXG/FSHtMWQ2OY/nM3UlMxj6F13fVZm9/tHQH9do2SLNZ9TwHOohQjABCUw@3fSs7hmEpUd6SJgiUVfYcgjJCzpjnR5NxjYd@ZxgSM1U0GFXMAkS7MSUDL4kxmqCjjFXf8cg2ChPCe/oNlKLWJa8sDTSkNK22wxPs6mpkzIt2HMnmjjplKAazUzDC7rSFRbaLl/8kiTvIEaAbjutvQC1K8LKC7SP1eki6PmJxWnQSRlH/3xJybqI@cypKMUaKWUypxbjjHfAivTIn5JRIGRtMuGMUnPZ7NxpqNO5Zex1hIN8R7b4eV@1owR0nMCMPUPUca8twnJihYpzYHiqxpb/BKHV8S8Iv/GNPwYrnmayLx/lnZOfTntnT7KnvS@nvzmMiRbJZpXNqYy@zDYSS88VWhnzbuKnsUoLTajB016ywGlPiQ@LRQJCJJ89@Sl/9iVPCJ1mkKr@NCMESQwZMMnf314e4PNTaGaSWOQzqTnniWMGP/uy6ChaW/kTYygPHPkkLMymko/paZ8zbBEo9tP99UpcTsL86lLh2VLxGe2ELoLb3DC4wnqbC6/Og1tSJUJsZ2npOf0twQ0JQny9Df0SPbylfkpaE/E9CbWTkhaheppzO6mIraiOJzxB5YnKHC4VLi5OVMbH5SM2/K4iljNlORaUmA5a3JfF@hn2u2jHDyHXJr1DhCNhZSA2InyEmgNkk3zlLg51zHRZYD8nT20hdisDoeHNZ6zVotfv5bSy5ngLJSjR8JrprBZWC5NzdGqKJmbovFamFh6p4sbL5//xb/u/ZkaZjaX8hyF9jjK/ZlZWM/KVvtCvp@bXdWYjs45iK18z4zztgenr8//431R/4y8EB2/G6/RnY9nAWhlnNnJlrvIls7FCX4pLS9Tu//nnf6Y@zMuODblY5@uuYsRKhiJbfo95l96rGnop29KFWKywYxZgiIUh7c3pBwyjbpdWC3xMl9FWFdeBjnxl7FH0Es@GWSM2FZKTDGNPQZqRVCijgZyANCYULWXZbhizDTBvjKb6@bG3EtIO4GdtzhE1GZluPA5hMjQv2yIawKy0SPt5@bJReJmOzDvW0sampGRUSGzttKxdfVoidnjXD0btRtJKwkzXbsO/Cc498KEXNK9oT9ULO/1fhvlrYslucWk138Lhfp7tuPMDhpQbjL3fSBHUyYBoY8hGp64a0gj0uwjh5XK2IFLod6I7KZNPkrTsQdCQM6xkTmIqIj5@rlwPozterEpn@S8p8MicqRNBWrnSTntUc/9gTaUXo4JSjve8DrB5x8axOgRGTqxhByybvBT3AaeDpj9eZXjBTkhcC1HXpYjnN5t1X7/LpubSJlWam5q7DDqDcrol4d0ROxU3Jpr@ombeCSXXxglCLseCDrC6wcinLXo5zU@wH49bQJgUfdcahYqLydrSZfWuvlnmrCv3NH0jTd/QiEJLiNuJeMaKxqbsYiJbyjiqHAZ1XKnNbJhaC03S5qHHH8AglGGpteCWoLvDHpBEtbg72qrMHjaX98LEIzeB@OzJ0aJkrk5lYudH15QQD2roTmjXk8ZIQCAK7hoslOn3oXhAlE2a0XYvJfH8Jl6b@B4aDPdhH6FE7bB1EnxUlqXeNXLftEfsS6mIBDqurG2DnZLVIwIdhdiKUtCmcfCSdsBSrTXebHFBMxxrnAbahIRKp@Wc6qShovSyLZ29VhJF0IN0obj09NnyyvPVF8hyNqd7OxsMKnnYBQwufYLBGnWWNtl4Xi6nF9LyCCmop5sE9FlgcQEHs64bxzFhn2@cR@ViQQMrpBnWDafRkOr6uJJBxhCHgYcVgfYo2WE6m325doKOnZ02nS/0j/jbxAdkhjPhaH0hvTUO7@LIVKmuBBwos2DmoDjZp4ig4ug3dtmg3zpAtIkAtq7C9tTQLiJAjC6H/auLS5s7PB3a6ogmDBGc41JjB/U6GMUBxiysoIvqA4ea5X1RNvBOpnsAo1wsCdD5BDhNMx230teWppgdC7QIIbImPFZxhWiZjtrszNzZ66vq3vYkYhk7DR3D9WzLVlLuOJIZAsggV6/V3SOiro52wa6kWia5iajKLOAKKFdkd3gfvtINJKK2qGJkNesNo@x9ZCkyL8ahTeOqNI7AawbMYuHbpDR@raYXIIgRhPo0KRJibnSfY5MsxskeZMxT8HJ6zbIRfdsOQw4wpxtLO9qilAtxVoG51B0AcW5TSEtHCmsYUf5a5cTLMtpI5ihe0Tga0GbI0U41mFmS00yw1W0oAbCRddzQAv2v7W25artKf3Y@bLtQlDcrf0W/oxTPd@Nb1PgW11RtxwyBHS2WbW5hM/UrXJSIWQo6YGyMIIRvS7IiBnHUgGptR9NeJvVJYm6fxVwBdvW1Em5OR/UkQaAXPgOZ05v3KBQHu@vwszU5vJqWNFFIFT0t5Ijr/olt0WQubjWCJKR8AIilSRBRoJaY2@dihhcLdNa8fb13MYxd25nN0wmWlQ0Vqe07eSJ7kmfvpMx9bLGk2WJpDeN4H18w397LG@dBq6990SLm@AZvPPpjvJF7OHPk/lswR/Ufwx1PNXc8XYPsEe6IwoazRyenYe/P4JjzMa/B9Wb7oo3zoZb1E50ouBYAFnjAED6k9LJYQN/uECcqO/vF4uR6BCOhpWU4Bvyhzj/TnX@2BpnLX7eD/6qdz/2dO7@sO7@8hrVmxshr1c4Kt/736XGsEmaTD2YOL9RdKeb80Z6u6J6urGE1nTHM/997mvt/1NPnuqfP1xAxQS4cJHz9/dwsmkjlcKtWi80tvJQO2pVFHvvZXOlg79Usp2nz0OpchZdlaOvqD@O/qvFfhTTib0hDh7uIyDY02svL9lSc5UWz5FMOBScr6Yn010RGt/qrF6x4P6IXKBHSfLA11BsVUshdeRnfNnmx/hhL32jxeSjOItt1skxcnFsbaNkRFp14iovmq5NkLq1E68o2x0BWW0cHu4v/Q8jQ9T9pLzRCHkN7E3Q6ZiWxt2BHUdQp3RmrO4B9qPccCVbR5GRkR9rbO2KXubulGge2mFgXZ28S5KoN93@0l@pC37CycuPIiGjj6fpmVwXTXLO9kCfUdyk0u8u6x3@IS19oLn2xpg70xuAuUvn6wE/zYrxPW1pevm8NkFoePjABCy6Vv2dW/V8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/1tf3v)

2sable is separated from 05AB1E legacy with `5 6-d`, as [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/250088#comment557819_250088) by Kevin Cruijssen
(explained [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204652/the-return-of-fizzbuzz/204656#204656)):

```
5 6-di26qxy}363qx
```

`i` is `if`. `x`s are for Beatnik, `y` is for Poetic.

A bunch of `i`s on line 8 balance `}`s on line 12, so the `v` loop (`4Dveh`) body extends to the end of the program
and top-level `run_program` exits because [while loop condition](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable/blob/5751aab5/2sable.py#L168) breaks,
[implicitly printing the stack](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable/blob/5751aab5/2sable.py#L3621) instead of exiting through
[this return](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable/blob/5751aab5/2sable.py#L171).
Minimal example: [`ii`](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fpEzB2My4UCEzs7b2////uikA) vs [no `ii`](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fpEzB2My4UKG29v///7opAA).
It would probably be better to just
[print explicitly](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable/blob/5751aab5/Info.txt#L31),
but I already fixed everything and didn't want to change the first line again.
**If 2sable breaks add more `i`s on line 8.**

Spaces before `**/*/*/*/*/*/*/` on the last line prevent [Fission](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission) atoms from `UUUUU` on line 2 to hit the `*`s.
Note: an atom generated by `D` on penultimate line is teleported by `5` in `25` to `5` in `5>1` and nearly hits `"`
in `"14"` on line 1.

Answer (score 3):

## 365. [Berry](https://github.com/berry-lang/berry), 16104 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8;re;s0::&&1Pr"93"pllasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrlopstd[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 001-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;@,,,"364_";# _'1:,,@9
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD440TD@0ekQHWRFAmAAL9JkSqVStWl7qpWTUnV3W6SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uNl5suXL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuyJY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3R46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbEsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6Tza/fSjK/HVDPtIh0KNLWN2JXtVZZ@bhtu7mkJjnx0/eHDVN8s@kRybPbheJDXHdqcT52ByFX6e7Q4MW2eaXJa1q4EFQObEsEqZUuZqUBHa05iY3aV8IOCB6ULr6n4rsq5uQ2thW24xYzSezJnE21@3rLBtPaZ7bOpNdYvi2dNRx3CDiN5EdyemPWBn5mTIJkPTC9NRbG@sdw2pZ1jmyJwYPWaZkMjp@1AAtN1jJ8b8zHGhyX2Yjm3NIaHRNfsmJgnKAQDxSkyGBocz0ufQyPYEiIPpzINiWEYALSnEIP59ozMdMGc6GU8nDMrWMz29YwHQzpz1jL4@tSZp1oEwQDL5nw0N2ydmACcDiGOHl@rllIpmLGhe7/VYBugYynFiMBOwRsWqsGwW/JnjAtYgVlAiHxjRNa@jMYM2gybqOxWWz2QgfD/0wdLqluf4hVkuGgba0FepzRDuE9cZuPoIsNEzCKefHTxhXtdx4Q1@GJf3p5vAdPUJ295m8f1P78dZPWwW2e0IYRPV2Dk0QSwIZKe6NQUKibaEA@3jhqkFbLL4RrzC4oAWLcNyOZaDbltiWh6QpGbK4ID@r2VV@BWYVmI5FXpQPp7GfPquPjAtg0MZIJQiEr6WZxrcMzmWVUs85sCx@jxalzIrsmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYPcEHSOqeU8/ArwA2hlKIoKv2yOA1rQPdAp0toe6@sj05r70Al8l@VVVgSIUF4VIGslgADPbBZ/WfhRsZavKOzJELA91E8BvGSZJ8iNjJAhYRMq8FC2thTiiMhyefbeELMH1AHS8iVWhOwLgIkcFAEwq5Ug@3yGV8QbGpblJxt6mIxKW8zAD0peBDyUAPsZwGUGkVmEH7wDv9OAsWnAxTRgTBowE00DdxazgHgFCCtAUxZ8fA117wQy4vloPUI@cHQAoyK2kYmpiCSAAK3FstBmBZYDQsgiIeSzDMoPZSkWGPCxkspKOVYqMsBnOcOgbVQoF1KJCvxThfKoCAzaXwUCUKFMKmBbBaBqNs@ECLLVLIZD2iykBdSoOUiTAzc0nFrAH6QDylAhSxXy1LTyggihbFoe6pvPEnVqBWjdIoQB3jQoqwbkpEFptRKEY9oS4LCExFuMpzkidMQDtAqSO9AhICMP5SG4EBfcWjHL8adb46HeQW7NU3b6mLSA3aCAaISkGawePHOITShKBsBgL4Dia0ABWUBHFpo2mwuzt1QA0kDwRs8kBm2ZwLvUEEPFNBHkS308WaBNLVCJxvPJMPTTuJ8DjNME5mcM9O48DITelw4DF76FLPpqxGsXgDI59PWAszpTz1oACR05jbIyTk1r4Vciv56h9/qmN3yzKGuOMukY@sQ2Txa55PPpCFL1SEABA5a8itlo3IkpwXA1GKJrURetiHHGTthAS0VWVSpex@hP7YEhlUuR8lHIZOpOYGBZ5Fnm3q45GMCYvICjpqmaNFAuvPNUQiubnQihJ2IX83RNGL7vsO4QBIowsMzhl8sLGFkNYcz1Do7qEkhhMAqUcdzqmzPWudOlUWNRwCzhqTs0x0HkytrIkcalTGalQoQ2CHOvS5mQNePVkl86pp2Is3hSuBRgrOGSZXSkhgHtcxylcNxF0oVx1SGpYcE@E3YwMiYBacuDPIy6FrBRaJSujiMwjkcGjacBHHMiM8gExEDDOUWxlQbFpWw8Gjg7LkqpIOX0DNdlGBdEWy9NQ6w37XjGqynKUYty9WHMNmBo7@umFRaAxhF9QgIAPOMe5DdfLnbfdUY02IxwCLUcZ7xGXIEB@wwBPXTOjEXRF@O5Ph5bIDWBv8GFNijMmU7yNgnn0Vx5gSARpoMGB4CUFUgbpmt0Cfd@1SF1FuSS5SJWmFa/k0Uo9yLiVBY6C4gaHqaxp5ZVATnH6LJsXekZpwr6cJFrWdTCMgRCGIhSPoiODrIylpxKEUK6o8kk3h0HLes5o@Wq8fH1IKz60ETByDrT59B6fRhajZk@AomeodgMPZeNgGJ4C2JLgM6C1TpgPceOT0IoZy4IsVDpsCYkKCNOJubIAO3HgSTY4jkqNI7uVLLOHEiZsJWTSd3hJbmCKFm4iijukYt48M4C4l5v2kWsYd6mTRQEYpKHMr4LrJL7CROXNZs6/FyQ58a@hiejAyMeYdEiCoLHe7sveXcJIsqohu2BWuHJzET9Cyh/4PSB2M5MqDswLEi6gN0lJCAKQq@Z3JUFQjkS0OjEYibrjscM/GFQAvJ8kCmBCOq8NNlrCLSGoEJ0p647Z7MxtIQ5gliTrtPvA/W@NsZDAMFGPdadd6F7QiMj9Qg9hxhMd7xczcXbpgFxbFRK9p78IhsYgHYQWPuonSLJLyowHlMVCBW6zYVZWwdMYRW64zmhRYgtUvQdR0b/nmN4RCyOexJ2fczMMwbUNaCf9RfMaITCOVCpTUpFDziP370QPmYorKwMZuVTwUeGDV2nC1QJnR6aD9t0l/VByY6IsKhn6N2uMZ74dOIQOzPtiLx/@ADlffKVfGCyNxQ277LtK1QDUUPKiciyqP9g0ce@GqIjr/U1eYkEj1Dl5JzFml/LHmKcXsldfIFxlkrwQlxThjF1CVR@iElMJ8hKkDua3SHywglyG5K3obe50@vVB79o9u6ISf0wbyyNCmxHkJXQC8uxHoYEP@s6IHlsIaz6kgdGXfK4BbTujVZAdsJCWr2or6zoMjDF24COHNtZARWQGcLFKMsh1BZEjEfINXQrJEbqLt5SGyHDXkwu4UAGY@h47LjQMzjTmdNMAjVZhLp8BTwRjhVJmd1bHlphyIjjgD/BURASjC0daAG7GPZU0Kx04BTAxLiCDDzP4TlGCky9nmD55Tsj1s@JCcZS2zZQOdPdOQcC1YPhGTKaM9N1gQ2e4iDBx6BgMJGJTmFM0Hs95KyIDur3VzOXkaL3ph1zdlUL76Kn/NITTnWX9VEBd0HogE6UiPe9eLJK/pQyEiQqzniiUFJ@FyEiRZKhyRN90OlhkHgAjOZobncT4lIXE9NMnE76JTEJDkzIZTT2MagKV0uH6gMSzegE@jW9VdkAhm9JgruEflQSDFBkDNBdkDOgE4KWWS73Ojq7AO7hMmm2x1WRQCVR5VyYl2H3wrx8RGBZovWVeRae2yWHFBnVsAYYnWpOg8QSAt8RE5RQBA9F8cdW9CBpj4eRXMM9pzbNw7EEF0WS7DwUfmEASFBhTBA@zK45afviyp07geCyUasBsYE0BWyzl4xqtMGEpQycGiLLJI34mcgT52iCfSORhPpi5EteGhCbgFJrdXY@GbrQ4@j9UoBIgFbBRkoOEOu386fmybR3taFt9MRIIvY6EJrM7kSsCjD4895Quwmr8SWsgtYbR6wi8WJ6An2NeMkXG1T0o7mGh@JvzS9KpIUTWAKfVleiiCf1/RYEvTfvWr5IwF3Q2Tk36kDxT/yJrJARpX2ZIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT3aPH9b8vsgDlY5pV5Y8LKerW@S9idHFIO2jg3tPd5/@YnsFDMvsVK56KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2JhwOY4o@MFMcmYRUWnehcFlFqDz8OknV1ECkhCig3IAN/6uiDQ8DghdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDLMEkQl0kHLIAZOrDoGK4H5Xkyff0aG@9qoca@P5bMmuocQOCpHNhBOhkDrwhgQVCnz0dESgtSqGnjQsPCFY0ZlOcjlJqvFoZE6QjJfHT4YP9pjcD682oSRVG8CchSutuTgeatKajgq@IA@wNXl6XkRcFRnqayrkRwt7uE4EXbsjXwAQDqOrLDJGsUVM0bQtn3rtaNfKVuSAH0ThCuypVReaj7vgWNlAOHuC6qvKtGUQpYDFah18oRKwxdHra6@bxRzJWjw1Z3kWcvCpQWBWAcCORGF4JOPAl95IUU6YvVfvGPHl0ruEdCJKgCUlAyz2Iy5eVZAmovksninrIHGppjGfLnxPFEJiYVJR6sC8hdj5TPSPz9mTlJZJL8qSYhLuS@u3ug3Q8i@1PWNJNBSgPq4jgyuX1c3@t6QCO2YzkDh21BGi4dBhmC2LS2mrsDx77WQjp6YlVjuEQI/BcnbvQxjDXma1IcKVVUXeWLjbrtnQGXVgtZRBJhiEApFF9@qZ/qgK5FvY8OvtyHQUTNZzKhO0MXoCCShtCFrm7ElzyYBBnJfnlWVjBcLrzW24MAKbJeh5X2GV2YcHcRvNKTOKasrIy/skgfO9cw/tKZXyEt8OGkBY4Iyg4@ffLo4NP9x7tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC4A4yK8DspA85HjD3rrFuyZWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyL8AaquELrYmPnaEd95JXK3OGodJLu8tJ6DF2Ph7VTwiKds9CZcTlq9U4niP9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedl1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQoojDc3eAo@uQWiw5xmEHVr5IDyQmveyBpYgoOnWSvLHAxBF8aFccNNyiEFU22UHmgIoCsrYd2IAdMb4NZ/Bu0kctL@QNVKnK7VjJZTxCDaUveHuBt9A1SnBIxWgIrklVfWvNO8w@bApRHSVSAxJm/RJIfHcCywGAiSNGuKen6AHOIWOF@KvIJw9GqKs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpk@5QmjgSwJOcPs0bRKiw73V1uy9v@Y6gsCD3fQhVzTaeN5t2CwT05h0qG647N@athtpKVtn1JFt@/GQVqHepeki7gQfQLjmBNOnJ1vCznn6dnfV06l09pkxGY3/Mkcbs8S4IUq8d4Nc9I9r3MIESDVS2luIqGPmNsmJCyMKkAt4QUwp0KBhpgfQULJcEQi@Kh0A5wLciCdhiNoPXg@/viPARVLqR7k0n7tEaCco1OFvqjQGJNNncRS7t4fzgBEbHkPKRS0PjIpNmZ0Yc59F1j89WQiJ/jT9ID7paCIFm5cMZaTvc1QBEQKlIPQfOAXSF06bDxSwjKv1AaZAhlQknH0CCsGn1YAB8BhLziuzyivCcyGe5Sie2c2YjtI7BSlLHnPDJfmfq4lq32YvWDaJnNR4HoFHlInydFsU7RpfPsvLEVAtQAnU2MkYOTiWAdEWswKAq6HxBHXVBD2esoVtlJFwxBPgSu7sHXKxr8PkiaYRKFJDUPotPXGVX@lLRpddAzTfIVlj5SBP7jX4cIGB5ewPNkvgzoCSdOCOK9DnNt2DgvUDcFXDFEGoMFCbqNWds2Fd1Pq4RJpJV2oYQj/NFoPP4xsZGvBKvx9Pg2gHXNrp20JUC1w65JHJhPBldlCJNLgxtUAr0a8UvGwHkWbKFNDBDyeG1OU7ojUol20rrDdV/avhMQlMA5iG2hA@AE0/WauhMJsX6Ga7ZgPweqfse0s5R1zXHPgo@BoGAv/s4yBISQL1Had41qqib3oyRUc0FpdFAETPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpTJ6t6DfRDYF6TxEgeuM50DIJbI1eRgLclG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkZ5MflhKpnSO60TcAJpKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQTn6JmgZlpWIy@clyL@TbCVTcUibjKeBLdficcALLTh6VGmcEeBE9MCcASqhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb80xsO5G40QzrqBlI0z6Iu9KrilB7l4lEu@5umjAt2Sph/IvTweCLc4eYfy0njOubvAS9pUlnZGBePuqdQfORNd@UwGpUmODJfxjbgiSTASUgiHRNV@bHrYhXXbcKZedKZx5QQo5g6@x8MpMMtge1oaqMocC0Z36LD45l2AzsL1HhxKcOlK4gtgAYBeV4YfMlGUSnCxBKQL2lBkAl@krVg0K6NSITjrCebm84XxKznMrUppWAYzMge24xoSoARSCLR7ivbkCfVgXfqAZr6urUv4oTSkoeJtGsARH1iOTrjl7DqyHjQeRdKDfg5Jnho9wQL@0Qf2KPO2cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNogJ9bC1hr5AYrjjXvyZAZJhQQOuNFArt2B0HnGepqmFbr5fiUIQ6oAZA@hkVArtUHFDYIkFQKTfiPv82mhQEf/9PD@Pp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U5Epfb3pq2IM02wd6Mm1nZAIagvSvT6ynjjPhWj68rJuZ4UqzOZpaOs35XJ2WuTFd1@k4Fk0F3ZR0EX/qerql80moIHT3s8cg6z87PqrJlUgkRT8d3Zg3zkOuzpbj8yC65kjrrcHykMcJU9zMizhuBbs@kc34AQUMmPp7PqGNAv8i@gddCtdQfP8S@o9wvyfIyv4sAr2Gnn7EMkXEPaC44c33PFczl@i/VgcL46kUjwuOi9Keqxr5n076/SXvLHmfSMiarIV3jrz5XtAlHTFapDyPhBtDl@JEARUoTrg/dG28IsXju1vkcGXxcbgJYWhYwdLiU5BYcPkMBn0L5SpQWlBE53s4DZCwx7hKQqwb195YF4RQ79p8BnS2scRjC7EN6kAwuCko0gibCvPnvqvUhWzHX7P0OFt1QOenaZXtOl/lRp3K5eqcwmflN9sAYrteDTbcrYuGOcXjYTSCSmWDFFRNWti/VtVwm4ZHk@0CJakKngLqxEzLSM1Zcb91EVc8QkOfic3m7MOM9gXoJbhbcvOOMjCqtMdpDb6qQUjcl2E7cyaBxIex@MR1dwh8hqVmy6iE9pnafcfqSXyVDAiGcf0KG8jfpBDu4vQ36xqmG2zgpB20PCny18jez2twrzRp/XqEyG7REBB0n3N2cZI@vWANGPJOZW9smZMWu5QnTnvo75Syr@4r5TKo6@pzT/D3uNTY7tOPPmtkWhyCMNJx5avEW3EWbE8GwRkEJdxHDi7cqTMxJyQJ0E4EE@urylCoGS2SQPEBBs@gysKM/Bph0S@Mi0Vd@gZoqgkDS@7NR2lmJC/lvqVPJobNaY4vP65HN18n8rOpUfY7/qJDhWVoZQYkUxPDoIhVdnR8f//pUxko10vE93EFpwLdUe8OQUBZV@kAk9HKV9iHvTj7ENMkUW0XoKuB9tH20wNRV4HoQf@A3JF3DAw3AZ5JXHzpgjetd1FCLqH5CML9Vt0J4SgEljCSUCcCVllZ/mc2V7X8claA4lOESUB34k4FcGsm5altvpI9GGhIboUoca6swnhR20wQF9tUk/6GuhEuHYOGRUIj1KDRYNJr4HIQWWStVpXvAYC4qIC5A8SuKFJT0C72mho0fQ28QaQhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM34DO6x@BixCWQXvGymw3E9Tfr3VkXga@Fsg59zNSp6@cvqiwTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TBHTof1Vy/uklndhQSdDVkJTMViRgCXE/OMBPs1SOHF@0HkwGXkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiG4VMYb4zLQPoExPXKgNo/8owFR6YB6q7@RBPtsUxADNWt5pRZDuAivnF6RTqVTMZqOS4emfeLQek/oamdkNY8SYZh6dGJdT4mbUOm2FDUsA4@rrSudN@r06bYiAi17@Avq5EET6r4sDEKkrjylB82tr8h5eRPJUrb@9lQaacHNpFe3xJTKJYrc73TMdVEBCbgvLHiuiAZMCulZk3OyGpw1wKkYGI@AcXHtZVH1q/uP2BLe/X20/vM/f6MH@L/eOkMYKHDmMXS0YejGlpL6axvLT4ovdFvdsHyCfGqZOiGGXLeB7OouVEm3Qsdq0LQIL0kw/I9wScFvcaBNvIHUeAOZ8ZLzFcHguTqTVYtqNrDM7rq4V/Zj8axo@QcUux4hgQtBpkGJiHXxRjBmfAkmomIjG7u9UMGmKUbEzNt9OJ1M@R0E11sb0Rzj76a@6cfM5PWOaih85/oNTe7qJ9OeI41PBqGcWlgRd1F7WgOWQBzwl4Pb6FxdfV5BvhM8eK6LthjalDN63EYVnj31xlKHtPAef6OOMLohB9fi93VRTP/wXuhYjzXTots7UqIPHQjF3w2h4F5TKYI08wqaLb0zRxlk@P5UFu4sAI5T66ZSmeyapeXxeH161CQpfbm8OvVM7nJ8rJojUPh@VonPolGF/R2ut7QqDFfmSLckrRdxrmXmqzYmXIsarmlSGjx8QScwbiRyHJC6U0t3F64bSHxRjmAZYd2MtD9sPDG7DogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gat8gItxPTLbL9wVyFxuA4iRS6VrMApzvBLaNraOodGBrfqokbYiNEIjvrMNV1zvC3VnwYgmrK76tHtNcrS/UOzEmyupYO4/ja4WBpchAnH28h1DPTM@i2GrEnKws66Vor/Ze7QDDtF53Gu42sPdNyPHZE95sQNHABC/y@mqCjuDR1W6LJ8Kj7Bh4U7HFYNKhuDRyrUBooOtzWtvrU7SPf95/vyuFCDqWqt3CoQPxxbNV/ruXrJ4p7clsD0YFFF/e3Rpw3DLGr2JS/9rK@dqAY4MLd6po9yJQopazwqb41GeOSy5k@D54/x9CxDrXB0DGekzgN0h0mKJfAMXG5iP3z5Ja7ObfeuzGla2CLt1Ui0rgnlgGDFd2vNSnTMup7plAzmXdnUX1rakyNlYrGYeelgcfqb1Ay3r1QGb8am/5MPS4O4NGUMNZrXzN8p1LjOI1vNzIT3TK7xu2izDJTG4P0PUbV@Qk4nqDjeoqBPR0vteqSdmY/vRllw3HQpZ3eUukw5H35UOkWSWlJPvcM@t2oMXENDzeI1fKZTMYXYCIrLksvN2lS2TDtS5PflzImn0XOi7i4yuZGnKvzILREtyCuZUHaOsWeIpfLim3axmSO93fkph3Hsd6npYCp4oFhB7RVibba3tRi18Qd/xAJW0xdeDjh0emvm7Tgo42vWwJ@UGm@qdGjS0Lv1JoSLnqOcEFq@fXm6ZvIAtNtueDhVpwT4ptvrfWypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqtMxLJ0/ZoXcTfDKcvZGeMtMw1@sxcVdvqS7WIqPXWFK4zkgy@yBljI0Rga93iDl6z00keE/1kaaOfhbFzwzjK4y2ze66yKMTeALNt6X1pAjwtLEsUG/muA@P9RTLNxJ6vuu48DBqt9KJB@M9IHBbbbcxCkXExa4m4ardQvn6qmLCt9B04VkC2Mc60kCOtWJMfeC50qAj@ddaNfp6Pbptiudv4tzoO/Q29dtYb0@xNpDZ2gPjSHfNx6@rescQI8TbmPnpqJDqQdD3Mo2Hi9tcY/i03Is613wiayRM0rH6a8s0z4efsWTW@8Fl5@09x@3Tt7pE8470LG21wyNKYxLnjNxxoZEb@uiWjjRw@/reGiwSP3zziDdqOcDRoLnzwv/Vt1yoDuT8Zge7bE19ehGSSU6s3yb3NTnW1NoU6TjDuTXzqgj@56yv2@FlsBXs5iOOekO8dA4p2xj4HS6Q/O2QvuGKpRgyoe/vpPuipgxmXQfvWXLBPS6cxnppRYNP8LHwbpG92eP@LAWOm6QV1bN0NGxbGmsn3Q9PhuKLlbBCeFIb@SHtyt0/L3yampOFkAje5nC6V2@LIGOdWX3d0@slazojMSCDfu7KtZSKQnpKJBLRgYEHnVdtsv73CJdLJvlt3UFitaSShTZl/I@6Pb3/tDsoBmZtwX/Jfpa2rS0cpCzh9OBd51h8un6HohoeFs/bUF7mSNT1jBm6bb/WIdmzVLwkCM82yBzTY0b11TyNy6qUDzVknTHhEcbHtB007VzaJY59vidSf21S3H@XibQxa@uF3LczFcr037D9Iw@XwJB120i4shxcScyyCBSF1fScQYdmTkXvDjjsp0BMHXJYovIQdx1YsvKbUKrmz8cM6UvPjUGOu61fmROcLPmCqogkl21vehW2F@f6p759SnUbB2xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeI/1gdl9uNQQYSF9BPs7PfljifzR63pbnA1ND3c0hY4bJqaQ5DgRI9W1QW9YEfPqvH1orGLRgfgxyJWxV82tO@M5nhabk@umaXVzQrOs/nOd6rhuE9iNhTibjsZTz3@sLgPtmYrOQo9OyN87MwG49ApYKxvq1mT1THVkyhWkMH9QXDjXSeNfmpYzYF@WMgyENhDCUDhfQTj3YHh@ghtyXHsFJVLe77jsiRMdkssr9gra1sgyybTNyc2zOZMJbs4JnlgZPnLgCQXlEd7lu@8LQTpejZFHt8v6i6PJt4zvQHlHztTtGugM7Y1E1QI/V2Mv2H2MJzoctJdyFtXSuo4F3Qsc1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtamImTAEl/ff/wsGaUG2q19mxQa2CNbuNZuGLhCZKYNgth6ProcO9Al7nM7SU9pq/AtaXbRmFOX2PV9Z5W@82QOA8g7K0zA/Kej@0YXlw1vzftT57FjOzAajYFRjp4a/Mz/0kaP1Qkx2SM81Q746d2azRGBXTMIcWlDHxsdaF9r4XqXsYgDvq9P9DVDEc0Nkv4Xum6lFdPqGO5LmvSLuNeptMsFemjMSLdYTzC8D0qTbpeLxDgft9RHllZsvLHj2PxO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vftCuYwb8ZfmBVbqZ8tVPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6urtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxySQvrwbeUjxRh6yUI1Akj3VPVqkX61qLECqs/fYAjTU3a6DK2G@44bdORHDBLew6XBvP9840AHEz4Bj6d2pbyz0tmJZo86IbmsVhkhrPjU6eCqoQ9Y8JvrsemPymSHflEFkR1doACBgV9ipCyzxBLSR5O3D1pIetYxVc0w34tRrl8tps45km0b3tY6zZg7hazE3vRQOdVY@JeeauepIN6JZZEWnk@4re9Ly1jUQaCxDmgxd0PmVyU3T24GZlRXrIdORgYvMy6swa0VXxxtSZZ3V6@khc3UNybf1B7wktPvH5UNpd63kieDh//DexwoMwu1CLjA9Aqzr9hV8KPzUtf3Hu1DgE8eb9M3ZIZQbTwGsYydYrTwkgQfvGejaWlcJaD17avHZh0Fk39WoR@qYRFaYJckidj0xJMM@lcgQ3Ox6jRx@6EvZReu9E6Mn@XYQcKVBehSc/wqj@c8VC6hR3oibPVWFI3ZWyPnbP1ch9yzgDCBvORNp7NFTGXtPDh4dHstjT105Pu0O8XTENTluybCCVspEpqRe6m5kvZNvR@uZ3kS5d6RKe48OZIywBt98RUOCB67MLT3WznsGVlwVfa0WhKHGZLWA@PD48aPU4ogmS@wNXWdkJKPBe0dHaTxp8vHRyuBo6gfQO/rObG3yg31VTa4g32c2rQ6u454rcloH6dgAbRSI8SG3y3KrcNV1xkbveD42PoPBEzm4947ZF9ZW8lP91BxgL2TltYiijsrKciGXjOzMBmXbcMPnuvY8McfILbv0UPhj7XYUlByyiptdLT3ctOJ/VYphGX8nwvslUjPXqTVqR1jRvb9vwVRVXYfnI70P7cryaxtrOcKq9WHLOX2HpWTDV16k0EuaAFVJ5q37yIvSCFi3gjecnvc9wdlZuw3mJgChd2Flhz8z7LluS7SWdZN4UYHUuKntxihfGu@wIBXu8DlFY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8paMj91Ikr29ewe3JXjq4/LmWB99@ow90T00QnJzxGiJjXco8UIyeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV/rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFoZ2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1eNVV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIcHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@3tEzQwVkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtbQRblFBo/kSm30kTHD7Sh8NniVUr9yfCvcMPYVk@uHk5vCSjeE5W7I71oYerKsnFFvAJi/IYzl5TD4kWOdDR15T3cNb8X@45UFuqki5RsqUo5wZ99aOi0s@u71Ij4eXfAfK6n12Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lXXY7aORSfYYjaVfD/e3U@gubW8ZOP6RD/6@Or@zqbEyo8f669UBxGlOVgYBEzSGUzoScT14eYG0AzKvYQ9Mbl@R3XMm@/R2g2IWnnhevRfBHN@fjteXGHgjfpLiKjtfivg56MzOmcfu4dG4hZi@QvfH/XGr/dfJtCycGEQzow@PdwPqOjxStEiOi1J88WTJGw@PTg6PIn6uMZutU3ql2TodcmXIItdPj3NL2W7Xn5@uQNb680YgbgA/Dp9r5SDO7D4@us4SUH0bTkZWEPKxbi9mTJcarOdM6KThysAn8xlto1zZ0kO@i21VmNtd4b2k2MOAbJqQt6e022hZv91eR5XHxhe09gBiEJtwsYQD9Q0vGbPcMCghJVnbUZ2ThfCzVNyj8dC0ZyuDRuvS0C7SxEtvdTfYZUeWc8YehVaF1rEHbTVw/dSw1zGnVYcVpXL2Zikse0WkWtcu/Osl/mNdk9xbJ6hd4Rm4IeJaCD//CuiL2k730r71G35enJ/S9eTAwH0iYadSyeTy14SiR47RwnBiEy1sbtLxYoh7ccE2/CO9ECAGh4T9Q8xoiM@0pwaeQubfGJnUNiGbWk3Nl9kOfr6nAgpEknJELzJ3FuTVYJvn/vncSkW9ZBs1JlZE5p@QDq0Xcwu8ABdth0KdmHSiss0JhGwGp3sZfUyCXTCalAAtSM1n4E1WonYOqv75ZyjS5vmTgyf7R8e7x8@OGpnWpX8@OqiEbUNugRWGD7M9Eeruow2EHW6Pm87lW5AdfegCJzO8oF4MP56zXLXaUtUWlRJ3MM3muW0rCh0RV6RLKJ8k8twoFLsseHHYQY2pfXzrABV@WpsOnUMTcdAi5QltVmGZVRmPdRi4N20//Oq3pigUv0VWwa@RYca@CWUgxIHj9PwcPYPdfgU5Ptg9ePTs6T4LCrggmjOzNxnWynluYZubrYB26pu0Z67G4n6SOLRVrRZ/EAfExOU4q9ChfrJuDXQO0QLsoDkAP/UWS2wSfMBgPGwU5T9/Q7mMy7j9Owlx40Gh4pAtkDwRysbGBjsGImH3nx58tv@UYfn375M3oghBsGM8UfxnP@7x70MEFn@C77C5IxplyWKKELUqEBy1X1gDQJxT1x2v/xobfY@BztyHH4IIv2QjCPSdEKDbMzLWd8WQW5JsK/Gvx/l29oKMiIQCm/K40oA281yPnZqeiSf@sQx9NGG3TOy4OYnMNspsFz81hx@00@ljJVD0qT3hZqJ8YzExoDQ5ZDlptkmF5Z82ESMR49sbQOwdAwQw5tkmDOeTCnsJlIiz@RVuEUKS6vFrSQLQFXJJOGhHIl6zeecpTVd5@2v/RBlUGbgn4P6O755l7sHbr/hvfXD/Knc/V5DQrtvIW5QlWiC0a@nXgBckxD/iPvKFPZtb4VggDk35BXyVmSNoplPCOkbnOfC7BOx4ASfR@AwaDcgNWsy3vsHzM9xWAg1rVhQFSQqVApnOPhgzvhHxioHNQr6QUxUopHQaACSL@AM8Yc0BJpMV6CbCqTmuvQBBc3t7m4k4M2DUClXessqm/TwrvggLuglxhbMhFq7BIA0kWaSAsLqfDAaflJrEpMi94mocGVfPgVGJwnH0wnfbR4TIEoAsjiMDTazP8GOMExgvfUOxHfx8YeRrKZs@IEmFMYlcSVHw7VZ86kyAfKCTLr6HxO1W4EZcPgKiBUaPf6KU7LMiPcrXe9biuHXwWRa/r8nIAziobObqYBptW/FzBHGEICriKvJtPGfNSdNuKZw2GZDpD1cQsw3uX1YGa2iW13v3unXOxFXbmogsdvfIdnAK5AFUhiU0RcsqaiG5qFIut7JKfo38bKA6aALoArIDNgUso2uYL52xt7u3f/Dx4ZOjaxYoKWb8ajTg@/XtVFOS041W6IhHq7XcJPceKEeP7z0IGmJR6EKEGwPj92ui3lSTxcwmglyclLlatVUlvFq79SX@nJ@lv1rerHZT0SjRtXKomffIl3arSw/ozNnVzLXSKmzl8zcVaQFPiYDe4weGrxU1kTy/bLS26007Fr9OCSs6wvOYvIWdAFxNb2tTQWK/XjmsWPjx4GP8LJsX7YvZ1X1R3MyigTO0VzBxThYm4HyPSECkvkE2wCIFWQmiru19h1xGXxgq1PjHjblltKjdp0iBC5mbMB4BdRx8Jxm5yMLMqm9hdAiqs2V2hMDeFrc0GhhEDI2McltZiaTgf6yDZ5zwv5w8q8xk2pqWSCK3I1hpdpPR0gBeUoAOjdLdkyloh0@cMTfeTlsQ7huB66kD7Pf@lE9ZGOzj6Qji9enx1KDlIODcEiQGTMbDonJZCriEb7N0lkKrsJBfAy2X@hWXR718YpaUh8asZw6AtyeSaeBoH6pqi4V2TbHSZMfUjovUZotWuLErfoTHwKNofy/jtrNFAfSGLpt2z5gl4mfxZKUF@aN//Ozz03hSXEVLZGTXtzrbu2ptNyx@Ub2Zk@gTv3cGpmxXcYty@TqXAL@rgLnVt@DLUeWyPPQE@hJgDSX3o4n7CJwgRiT6I33MElObW8yTGb0mmgk7TabEpDq3xmmzVIoUKnhQgMwoZZ9cfPxO6PacJZQafiwSfD27h4/X5pg1VFlugZsySbJN/KLbHkhcaEMyKYAODEkqBLaGJARqBpSIdxKZEzikwXCICw@yO7gimD5wRbPmDuKEas3qd1jkC33LkqNYLlf8Bl3mimUG1HedHcoKgL3G5wK5HrDrG9MBnIH6KwuxBSO/zvFilG@MF@Shb4UHihOLWNANjPMwgLWwb9sduvhL7NvQV0A@qFSeHT9ol5KKyEJrPgPX7OGqDjcCH6p4/md7oJsqS1HjVa7RfYTJ0G5im5sLQvN9D6jDiFdYaiyKhqvfg1/QpqreSPV@Qr8VIGYOBwD/1GM7AIe2LoPpnhVhq5n9z36GX5wXE5uqetJ2T1PxfKYKN7WaZ3n24WZTkjYbmdrdTR20qMmrWRN0cmUrd//UGPZ7BwOlKYosy3KKsnV@fh5/sPXEfJ5nBalnaoVXs/lltpB9NbvMqqVXJ2O10JBfzVpiqZY@abEnT754036TFGen81diM6HF9g4vRDWHKn@sUmbnO4Vs7KQM6ifky9gJew3XSZ/hP7lf9yJuHd2dPqiwcZHFmk38XLxYFBWlEW/BP6n7L@Diin@jLtflndabN8mGrk9mc2aa5tjr9eDnDEGC1JJHDPTlO8DpeQKFNelJGhReo1n/@nxCnrHZrjEYTPf1uoYHYuW77ercnD6YPP7y8@B6htfrp5Fkr/1PyKZSCUlqrJinqLT1fAw/RvtnP9m4TJ8/aW//2TdHirGBj0N8fOfyMbqP1PyHGxsf3ruXy6U1TePuJ18@@cXd3d3c/XT@SSO/k5MyG9t/@icbG5q2rSkbLc9TW/HGyckXopbJifKf/SjefvLk655Xz/6f33hTV/FWhNspKwKfgCvLVHDivQQ/FWWsd71ir2NA5WpsTn/tWOB/vsHU@k7xv3zv8FVsEqtryucuPCexV7FCKcad4IC3bPB2GqvHtjFa4TI2V2q1GjiL/@XfQvr6xwAHQ@bbcKvnA1iFeawu1SjJRaxeAIeqaZDv//2Nb0RKyNlEjcS44LrLGnCJuaIm7rTg2qJrW0AriVJGUYJ49mQ4MRymlu6od/DFhBd42AaamzcmzRh@jpsd3mXsaSOVSrXktgSX/JwmiRRV1ZqqegfYgfThVq0mbTFuBzKbzd9BW9ZJmtIaODBiGnc@/4e4Yqs8qz83uKdCrLBx98X9eh3qlK1nt@opuvyORH2qWBId567I0uxFHFSQRuvFI8aN19bFTEkT0@n03Ta9zxBX0iykJLz4PRYLfbDLsqt@S0kgiu8be/94sX28/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PsPaEbS7pl9ZQsinUKXqMN1t1Lp1uti3RXPm/heBzrKVEqVktK@bCa2gAO1njI189FFPJ@NH/FPZauMNZOUGi7Ktu5nj@/12MK7zn3qUT8/gEcmD@bXghxLWCN3iLVr8WBo9TfcSo3TektCgagmNdRCviXxVPXgKrPGXWgmUSuWxVZdy2uH7G57xi823PSYEwPNsBDg0S9vfVG3ehiyeKtHvWL1IFl9Eed944XlFWKNhtIyaEAI/NjdjcpGqVKoaEq7vv4C0oy@UlTDMJ54sdNYeHHMxhYIjYWkedUvaIrwhQUUzN4nHkhG78J8qZWyBVWs@i6tzcQqEImWlbRBW8yoYtjbcH4frg34o3@4wle8b5CP701Rrl8brKJuaVkl/2FhX8Px9ZYrWlYBxgnW7XQ6r7sdkDp0vaN3dXWiT/WZPtcnnWln1pl0p12GXWZ5Rj/r5J2SM2OcAGUpls2rm7E7RNRvGhvsKedCLZYKrmbq1uuZLLd9Jzkc/EmSM4sJsX@Aq65qKtuC8SkDNxDKyAk6M/6pqsBiIGidt95sNd5sQQetp7aJObbqkl9KeMjtu62UdHnZAHe16v9v10NnlS7ugsq1LlOp7ed1kD6e1xspAPncBylLjIDK7Xprm0LCzPzc/ODtFsgvUmq7sV1z9ugnUweR4jknXnDutgDw9lJh795NyeC6CwDqm9Afk6nUpiRt4NjY8McKiNyqp4JaYRkSIC2cn/@cP1D0oBdfbl/WLxvbl5fb2/C/TfdL/wm@l9vX/umxuNbEWYS3kLU0G0q9qTR9ZtGCd1mpo4@sNMFRhyfEa2S1UquBDrjk1n@b/3J6cQ99sMgtGUotxLbYVgyNGmZjW0Lsxduv/hf8Nd9@9fsoLzL4MypC7By7tbKF2maZK51wY/Zjmz3mlw1u/AWv6IMej@voafObjQtSivJCZhU@559QS4WkjANw2@m30U6CzF5A1Gu8j4laqSC2U@pcY7FtsVAkdvcL1654PP6PXmjlYpxP1OBB/xee5z2OlHJRTohc1TKqpF7UuS17/tmRX1h1/aNfWHcJsYsyMyqAn67HOGaEGBBSTFEkCUas@vYIt4LjWomEaulp7Qvp2a6E8yj6hFbCunyOoHawXyuX63yZZ/MJdZut@1twV@F/fwPqwZp9iNvs17ojkICb/Wxea6Ll85jUeYV/j17jHzvu4t/TV/jHjl/j39MJ/rHHHfw7foV/ux38Ox7h371X@Pf4Nf49G@Bf82vZrFoVN88JNSm1rF5uzkRCUTW2U29@beLOK5ZhN8xey/@oTzZXZslY82vGDD/tXuGe/fhPv/vNb8ZrtbgUp0@l5FTHZWqyCtiHGnnx6t24EKuxTXVTzViZbkbtqB1wmCzjsswwM1R7oKi0VZYxWGaembPMyFF74DLgLwMuM9NnmQHL2BkbIkIouCbtzARdfXgM4K8PgFz4M3FnY0fNdBlkZKHQRl9ZRPDgumg3hQaLM/GFAbqmrMoZuWC28Ns0DfHFi6ay1dLKJSYjUcntxotmvCU2RbRXrpVzrDM3NpovRBiaMyInPvRhMc8DBbYaU5pNhaMJMEBYvLxst/c/vd9uKzgMNR87h4v/w8NR9PXG/9Gh8/jQGTnwf3h4CF3HqKfupoBB371bA4btP3Zi9epOs0JsP2D9MWV7p1nPSugupICba@iXes9rARGe9Y2mED9LoO5xhupH9fOz6mmV3GfBKzja1UWEIBp3@E@4zmCIC9SRM7hOz9BBb@g8@7wZurhD@fwMvD5noHeF/6DgRV//K/yb/239P37GkizRaCUT55fbCbqS@JdMnl@eX/r3ejKR8F8S2/CHHvCOSc4v6@ikSOfgaiSSreTlJfeDeyK5zQHWIZvtOqVdxINhIRZmSdnyW@K/7hOy9q9mvApyL9et8xnqRzGxyvTFvppmc5bJJKud4FMMuEqsX9DmhWSVvsO32WmorT/9EX1uYydJkfK5alXdYvxFy2nVai54K5aq1VLwsplIlK9f9cyOWgD9I5dLJqtVeNkJwGbgFdI22JsUq7Em3Ft37vBMStrFRQAzmyukMmoGUwc55SFbw9O7PsM9PzikL1UAq8nH8BMxnJUkMvSdG/yWWlysiHfuJPxvtO/sJu/c0cqZi4vQZzwGL3XJq93umW67jf7ZiwuxLdI@mHIe3jOliws1U06p8aTjJj7Fj/BBVglJZR9qdcq1DGxcyxUh2C9Afnu7kKvXCznwKZTiSVxTb2DxW1DeuBivirFzqoNaKnIOKFbRO7o/CPoyDgrs/DJGDcpy@WQCGGkSZMDLGP65yHP5cJPPJwEzlyKPqZbLPGqS5QqJUqrs/9U2QCsHIYf/oaSWTeW2ilt3QebFP2@26kKeXD03aupl7dyo4Kz6ZbXrf84YrT0Yd@5ky4CiUqbaFNrt@7vHu@12TRRFFJTghp7E3QU0guHGG1TzfLnFMVKp3qVmVkt5Bu3J40hxGCFYCZCuaFt5tYRIEsw@GnMBlAhcW9pgG4JGT7wJZY65DfAEdQYy78HFeqzDBnixASpvzGQWXcxiPJzu3W4YyeGXHxq@UlrS7wIfI7wEvxdmOYnCIP7k0e7e/nFa25ZYTHuwu5fWjp7di6n4ml@8U3AW35/u794/fAYJnjza3z3a/@jgs/1nT8DfY2eLK2D6/n3xjLpWvJ@xz4WX7mvdMHRjahjts@n07BV7aZptExrTmkKlnIHLPKMNdRnri3pV4dc1Pf3lS90d08Xe/vDbb3/43739ne@@/Z1vv/2d7//0q@9/G34/ht93@fO7/6acx/tPv/pnv/v2t38HPP8D/P4Ifj/56Ve/8Q3@o/c/ht9/ivj9sf@LxOM/AWD9yk@/@t6PfvrVr/4Afv/S//3g@u/XfrL69/1vrf9huu/97s1xvvtv4fd7HFYQ97u/zf3weS3@b/N4v/qDt//i3/H/P/X/0Pk7b//FH@PNf/mnP/jT//T2m/9e00p/@q/ffut7b7/1zbff@s7bb/1j7e1v/Gs1E7397tvv/8Ff/eHv/dUf/o/0/2O6/967/L/9wT/9i//1L/73v/hD//cT@P07cP3kL/49dJW//YMf4v/3/uBv/@iH@P8//6u//YNf/9tf@Z/I8Zvc8f/8y3/D73/9a//xb37rO3/1k2/8za//5G9@8w/@6v/41f/rN/7jX//3v//X/@Sb6PmbP/mrP/qVv/zmt//yW//8L7/51Zr7t2@8f/UO/l/9A/i8eznfBc671Ot9fb76ucrz98HGIhegE6DuX377G78EBP4vGHv77R/jOSn4rfn/saZSnB/zt/8POLTrdcaQDLjg9@tvv/1dRNH/ACiC/xBf3wlflkL4y3cWL4DW31qR6Jd/@tU//xG9xYxKnVZtcOwuaaXUFug3W@WyP377CzqQ5JeWoYUA/Jy@gxxqKew7yNve/vAbb3/0j9/@8Dff/vBXcPCWcuX0blpSb1kNg4j5d4iHEQvvEg8jfoH5p2iKTUp9AW/sCz/wiy@@ENoXCh7Iu3sBvl@QF78YD8IDe35QEIb@eIKPXbCo23dmfOem7xvmzFjjxYsWrreCH@aeItljKxCN8lk2S/kFmzG@rIP@EGm2Rc4Z3skXg2cC3hb/C@dMYKmZP90Lz9TCSQ4/nZ8Fdwp5yCY1CxeTSFZjXDra4j60Tkz55soMazCbpWagBIMDckhB0D0Qx2u1FCas8fLAKy9avcSoKKlUDeqNqXmadLuEIGb3CAqkrKWesvZWbcYTphBePUBHSkCvp6KqialS7T5kWJvdZwgLgRPYFy9q9VJtVkdwbzg@UrPUPSoTAqulZvU38F4jmJBOiN1/A0Up1VKpegkzxEry5km3eSPlqXJU9xRL@W0AT9zuv3OXsQ9FtSTyRYINRBiPjffUIjZGhOgQ3kxt@dWh/8BJvy1C@AZl5efCePgOyaY7XFzFCABXkmRZZvDD9fcddheCZxxUirKFR4pDSBFFEAWEHgznh1JCito3RS@Qf6y29d4XAsPKbG5uCrG6mBUPZUKdojD3pEJnH3A7IKoXFSYWyiJ6G3QQJCgLpK9S/ptxXFiLMw6YfZjiv7t3t9iHUE16LvwEJqWyTs6JcSjbqZSoAfy6kxKeg1oiAJ0SoAtBntVoIS8lpNOMybUYhrHDw0O/EOTxvCakgMy1rIrvuJw0nU5jkEKW03I67T9lepKH7DtkCvWf8iYil75SzTQtVwXtqcrQi0VVHRVUYPR88@YNtArtr6ocgPLJ/K1WWq5EgeDB7ZJY1jw4MKTlygLXzJlayDGWoClWuJIsKbAE20oKfFc@L0RwJeJaqRSneIB9ObEV7LwrqEQOOL0aq2NBg4urhKV8MgjcO2R7h48f7396PG61mGDQV7eN9th1uobnJTBs99P7/ESGVi4kY40Ggj6uaMhghP1Khpjxwf2nB0cVxivtN0GCClaldVW/mmVViI3Hn2/H/J1HIn44zhGP8F5Z1C2hlbOQNFYXYl0DNQtcMEcFuMqqwmNvcM@ZgU6fFsW0WkDNLkmTykz4RWfK0Kwpt4ECfQrPacjb24QBoX4u0dIFOqG1CkK97u/ZY6pQP9o/hgTHh0zVMrJQ/4LNZMxQuhTqVs0y7MFkuImb38RmRozUabORSeOfls3CXc0V0mq@2NrYsM4lzLNJzXaOuxgv4fVcwmp8ABcTPhDYB@AFF@SBWxOZvy/04LDqb85DA2IJvkNPVPPQzZICzmNzcMI4elWBupcXgoTYxpdfTli9Dvq1dPBAiAG3GLJgf5pk9uShTM3cm7oGhQ4Y65mfmfhFQLlnemNLn0PXAWzELi8v@wDp4AHT6hq98hQ9vF92yacD7suZLsTsSqX2Rs0VBe2kUnmT1TQBPIQtBTfAbQAB0D6CLYX/VT3IJJstKcCpVFGERzabFXDuWBAqhsBor8ibTK0mcRrM5lTaKiLgRyb0WU0LLz/u7MNF3GyGx8UQCGCDicsyQViRh/lvBYHeAGm4O44@aVz1O2fmzp0sTmJkc5lwtoJqzC6hbTazuSxiXPj/LzyAxVdztsf1bEbdVsbg1MGZ21Z0cHbAmd9WOuA0wVneVkxwTutZNbOtTOsCE7a5CVGGFkpq4sSYocVi7ifWPcPqy3i2qCZSBpq47ZvkrgcJ671az@nS98irPdnE78LjeWKeIJcTq46Nxu1qaOaCTmCzRPJcGNTO6NSzYNQGMtpLcW3dEnpyx@nNZW8yt/CUjuW4tTiIg/EgYAHdADkE5752stlcpcFa8tgZ7whavphqqBkYQPCnltJaesPYKRYrPblrGbq7k6/kS@keHgDyl7h28pnKQP7i8aOHk8n4qUGngnZyZUiAFsbQFtBOqZLPtxoNUUw1KJsWfk2ZsydpYwP6tKH3JHjiApgnaaUWJO6Zbq0Wj@9kVU1SK9lM6VJYIA5xjjWsC5g0hTVLI97PfQ5QsR0bmE0lrafNc8JCpd/vX26dpxYvgn4u8TfAz6Wkpzvn4WtVisSrsGlaMheB4KP3Ad3n/tpeRdTyJbHaqC7eiwWx2roU7o6MnqnjYaBm5vx6qgIwZQ41Bhk1mXBZcR1nUukYfcc1FhGzaiGIyAt0PUJOvAyza2Ywx/Pr2RUikWbn16Hk8uJlmCoolnB5CXjnyAa0@/Zh67RptqGWc619YEFAPtuB6ViMFnv@XIhtPf0sW69DU5/niloun8tr2UIhX9RgvCnnCvkSdLZMIZPXNICSK5fKxUuga0V5E6Mvw7G984DeK2QbP6FXuHHHRosl33xqWuelrMTLkUhWLy9jb4TYh08/02CAXHslYND9TJPqtWy@DK4surQsFJgJmiZpWSmrSmoW/29xaPj/7vE1@NfwDqmymnCMFl8@hWEThnqbPULLEROHHTv47aABu2d018TYG@q0o3nPdTzv7xHnnm6f8KD7JjezGgY91PEDat7InAzXxHg2HqGxGMP9B4OwP@pAAZEd8gj34OZajrMqQpE9e7Kmlo9Dw@aADG7ZHKI/Pfjo4XHkeby/u/dQKLB7h5/ev/LI@5Hy7NH@g@PwtchDg6T5EMQv7j96dPXVf@QOnz3tTx0Xf8KDw2e5xS30wgOzQg6u5UihNwHxb/hKgiVIFKCI5YuBQxXwmMUdUI7v@M58YeHMoPNzfhrY9MJt//xgeEU4Do4I6ww5bcdgXW4TCLV1stfny/JqsSwIY2Y7Z6yYYT3HsnT8Gnx/AzyHOh53NFCgtSykRMz6zHGt3pnZMzaEx3iysqzil7exEMJDADKadsnWAwgzaP21h99px2WpjjU12HTM1nrCA73Q6ZqDIYzBZ04QQejoOoPf@16Q3ohek5s9JjwP8rsWYl2PLsQEUdwTxYf6RI@Vqq5R9TKVyp076hNXLGfFMeDSGxj7MyBa9gw6ke7O0yVxIosPWHuA6xqWMwYNpAHyellrtHZyWr2UyWdLf/1bP/67P/n1QU3damb2Mts7jx/lK8DXQIRlJKX6kqxMOo1WLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLgzpYLINGkFFLaqGUL6vpUq4MIkiuDKH5ctGXg5VA8FW2KgDW7uJnoLdJLZKHoP/wNUj2OqEnWUwP36dMNCCNKKAGOqFz41tmDUZPpmZYtsgAos66LPbgwV7mwQNRvIcvuIdjLyOKPXzJlzKZ4j1RNChkr4TilOjwNCU0qCdO@Esmcw9QPOUA0Ba9KA7xZb@Ac2miaOLL3u6DB5hPH180TA/RTngIf7GClyJEs/EFxHMC8CqEBtF2eT45Kug@vmCWGPKAh@xBmCh@FBQHQ57yaBzAw6Cmu7uieMBfdncxZI@qnecF/QRfdukSRRdegO5FcQCOgQs9ThQ74ETqF8UuuLpzHfzwk9tortye6KI45@hBBInijGLr3RNRbAf@mM1nfmnyiN0Kvai81nfppYx/oqgFhcZo2fAlK4q58CUHdXv48DN9OOkZA37NXf7sQk0fPszq5my6/6Dz0UedwaDjznf3P3qKQXt7D0EUmU/dzqDjJ@y04XIg1d5DTT8Zza9eUOuDdruiWyuDPmm3c7p9Jag9bxtYQkj1CkrmXwPMaNTeg6C9h@27@qo1ZALYxo4/gmcHr3sjeN7TOzwouCiInrNOR6wi@StKMyGgsoCrv9gdT4CR2umR3nWdKr7PaiyTRnll3ihkWlUKYCMQ@jPVSwzvJ/Cu48RP8nzemNUyrdqsVtT4JqR@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pV0HSF04@zuKTusIR6Z@s1S3ya3NFAARCbOzuS2FBbO5paqhSKz7emopis4H0nW6y8TmTiGcbwlmwUWzvFfCRFsZjSFa1SLIIYBjiZwGjewfmYdiJxZugnySSWlmYHoApUVzaneprVfmKWntV4udg8WZ3V1Co308sy14D10Cb8tDtxXA5yAOBmO5kKLr8nRLVcEqEAipJIJkOmB8q6sNj/@fnXj0@Oj78gea/uT1w84R@xr/qvHz3ckw8Ogze05i4/QDHUceU95FpLIVweDbyOQQGRH8IICspc4IdHBF3Hkvdp2xzIskFAYJ9I9i2ryscPl@AcDZ0znjNaWKiSeT67azA0dm/2mF6rg0vvsQSViunJMxq72/V6rV0bkRECqGKQ6hNGluAXYA48XvbQ7gMlP8djc35Au5a5rHZqs9gM4LRrTFJfjJzeCy3VrfbQxv292j1MXG3Ds1M1aobrOq4IqrRY7e/Ytant6X3jieGiRZODw02QJPAsXaLPjOQma@5j7D1UUy6lusvsRck@nY4SulTvJJe9cFIu9EDkJL4eVPqcjnfiBo3Lar/GEs8h6it4dzdZoiffS@7kqoCne6ydBK/Mi/6LPtNYIVclNSOBsKArEX6w3jpL1uqfwIPDPqlUoDR@Q58AVMwMAJs9CoDYY/Oy2q1ZLCGxGUsSknLVQa2ByS/wti2JYkuSGhctoS5Jnwt16K/VeUyvedMOfR6FZTqqlilUZ@CnFnPVITSv/nxWdWvjKYgHFrz6c3n8JKteBaQC7gDM64vE21/6RnJbyte4X5VAXVggdbTldm1WtdHgIhBGLVuDgFQjl0mDAg@3YhrGfK2QVgvpbDqXloroCwN@Op8GT1BwQMBIWAmRMTGdmWVkNa0aajqReWH2XiTTJwkQWghpLJmeOPv2dMTAB5oKaZNe4QnoSWlbFihePYfp2xIRK7CMKlYMsD5kYzM9RFBPDd2iFMmkxLJbCWszgXE2j6fj/UarUtmfjb8OQQnp1U4hVcykXieT1cRGsuYZr4R6Vagje6FajzeAcv1pTuZNRw1oZXCpRa3SaHSwisVMOpvJQu3M9sVgW6yLrXRmo6BCE10yYhuM843ozB9KPAu/cRsFb8uAplPLWlWQaRouW9KkspLfymf4VCBPKYx99oaYZImmGJzaTsTjRS0eT8aruAixIfqzzsDTiJ/FgbvG76g7IghjYkUsaxhhwRrpYG4mKB2IY5cCzn2wHOi158Ll@eV2XfiacITHLbe15/hXfP549xD/vgZeZXgtPX/87PDZ4QOBKbTPU27HqhtVudquwosk1@8KsQpjwEmbvkkpZYOx991BmtquP@fPJh4dALgCGVFusBbt7DJMVNrYZ2iuYIfFoQ66O2poWrbV0Iow9gE3DaJqmlrFJZoYHk6Q69AY3jmUbztVx5N@n7D5XE9JgaZ/h7FBalMg9MSuTgPs1nYHT3eDzWm7e6snCzZnCs5PN0Fcx81ssfN4LH4Jf0LsLp071Pi5QxYLTx7isqq/IpLNFViyHCxYfC1@NxaPx3FloMK8NzFqt@Ak1ycvNCCZmO0EHqAw4WQWDGn5PE6fx5QXY@9LrZR9fHBo33cfGPzIkFbKtcV6DL8eLeEBqWrF986L7Y0TFUgmK2ZP0jF2N0ab68VySRM17lGNsROmBgeOAA54tONqJZ2@C4VublxsOLhUwsINfG/sj7/O2DiezcUZa9Zis1rO3xmu1uuSuq2h5bYiq8CY0FcLUuaizqm@TgEFDULe/tIPcrPtErxrGRXeNS2f0up1dUtjydj47Ve/j0Z4zvc/233E4jjB/nd/8iOt@Hd/8q9oD1r8kibdtWwxBjHRqRaKsfPz8fn5JVw8LB9rxXihcsUkuPkCkBqrK6qWtW27yiqKrm8VUzntrl1V/LhqUU3GPCnmb7vMFvJSIqEqUKqtbCmThLALP6aWKcFbsPTEo4sFaCOowP5TM6@pd7d3oH472ZxW3QASUcOjqSz82za8MhBA6fGLC8bgpVvvDQamRi5FYZU3Ett@I22zN7jw80baYC9qddxAoOKB1mBhZAsP@OHiYLyeUrbiDHQoVm9cVi9bKVpZAUXzuWFs2c0rNN3cwBMey15bNvwZWx79YaLAw4PX4M3YeumJia2kovR64vW@sm2wfB0IZktZHLtlW8F6Cf@TpGby7S/9hqYV/u5Pfu2ifdH@QgM9tFwuqFrsZz/bntpTz@jVfwYAbjDAEuiSJE6ipRR0hDoo43YaTT9V6JC7oP5ObZS3efxAI0UdlIGsYg5so0caqXCK8hU1bpvbAOwlKNoW2mdIk7xONreSVUEIBFsuj7uDbppgsC00LtpoJYVz4QMMguGbgUxfFT5YgAKPEQzYTrftWVN3TCdkEpRObaXZHUgCOXyA5hU3yK6Ez/slYILK1vWkvMgeYY1kMTYyPA@NNcKwJXwASXwLzNacjXU0gYIxTRsGGxmjUDkpoNeAvFuQt8UTtMk3QbXnEdKMl44nskFmFz4A8YOwYIJUwsxtiFAF1vUBIADqkPABmy22zbJJdm6mUtWFJchL3MuPtir1wPyCgMkQWg/NfQSJqxgPvEBXwG9@Il34LQxCYcQzAMJh8KX/GmgbmJzeUNAj@yjvDApgkS2yBFWN3bmzKFWtZvaSjGqE8E/MMU6UUTvYq8sKwAJN7cNeRUwztLFZDXxDsgOMp6i4QHUSN65ZjSRlIr5eCgL8vzPRIkVeaSoKqGIF/PbivaILKIPEiHbehl22XWOqVkyysPBdKHuXCkWH4EP1szn7UNa@CAIvoYQ/iwVf1AGmdRydfPTp9qr9DQbC@RQ/Z4JW2Dgz8O1mcDtryPwOJkHqMBVUxbQodt90QTGiPQmBicdEVk1isoVJTCoH8XEtx3DTez6JD0qFsRk8dTRV6OezQSaWug40qDd2bLJtSLaX8MQBUATwKN8sHC/21D7Dz1/5bUOJoyXyyCQcUj6WmGw10nfDKS1uCui4oEAHuEkzYyCz7qjHtDJLEKGR@To7BJekRFTgDsjXiOOOZYygSEeGQcfUvIqiDEDmmnbIht9jE@hq@MCEEcj2FP8T7cqZeWIqx2iHVnL6eJqNW0SJoZiG3Y/vP/Dt5VmOc8Is88Tgc8qJJXsyHgMNA4TkNGB28QPEVnBji5ZN40SHmuax4FeER5E7S@lI2o3EPHn9mVU3Em1s0Qsab0wXP79@qtsR/NJ1IfiqtTf3AotUZFcJ3uWQ5Rq@LZpaHK1MhEaWBN@2Vo3MOsm4VjFOiDExsEmFTmHsGqcMlWQBxxhgmt3Augv2YqjtBzQAUN@DnoWmKiduBW0SQUncXqILXc9n8Db7kGU1ASNyg2G@cS@AgU1fW4YOYZAU6@FNetAwMk3QI1@B3jnqQRhaw/DJD9MH1I1uMiO6IG@24YPDQYfyqjHeLYKXfOQFewfSM1V9AwILUMIVJdlIiCkAmxKTIgcdpr@anFO7QLykwq5DSjOE4KMaoJCooCPLQVuEke9UCRBwT/f4xwx8Q5ZnZ2cyWVeduqZsePjtJs@xdUsZD0yQuh1lYozG/ldyTfw6ug934ZL4J9vk8XC8M0Pptla@M@dPQeh7NX97UCLe9@I4OJ7ip4kGI7LEhibQPCKoByZ91qyb8HcrcfrTWunzgP4qSH9SKX6JQBhDMLP0PN1NA7B0p3uS7p/1qn7AKXVIAA6taASeaPPYDV5GXuAyx/0whjNBPhoGdawTWvEFSCKfEV5kzWsYxJwHr/772JxBIts4Y7uuq88TFJ7E2EjAiTmJPWwOwz6FgBOGGXbODfCas8a8tZR8FiaHQS3c7@CimTXh/Gag3Bozhs94@AzCZzx8tsg0yLYxa3GRDL0usTpI9WidM4iJYOZBnEtuuXgRQpBBHgctivww5nzJ7xJ@3RqlDvDN36AdawFhAE2MAeFGQmk8bzaaLdszzrZaKWUAxC4SIqDFAXSjRTg964VuxL51ao0db8nLRqOsMCr55Uav7tCnBk4rWMewgYgwOL5MtKM5GPkbM7hA4FcYIKAcBoEoGuxOEmayGlr/pkAgnIa4wDEvWMMvTIukLz/I9wNxiaOeIzYKqBUBhP5hlaCYEMKCnsO/1Bdwh89dB@IEcSX6uNgI7bnFW3HA5JWuwnlNlRopUipJCooJaEdxtXa1KkE4NEXjSlCkmpd@@0eLv/Hexe9Dv1hdeiJYPmBUhWhXwb2QIEL43YWwyuq1SLtCCZQt3TJcGLn2uXzqj9aQzZYSqBk8H6yCd2ZOusNEpPG7Sd4@dOJStMVKSArzWg2qOK/xbsn7RYBSjvAwmecnmweE4KfnDARgZFYmM/xks2iyWa3GGQebrUl2FinkjAo540l47NmaQrb8ZKA9HQTDCzZPC6RT3KwpAjyVD6MgBo1F5umnBi6fv0Rbk7gK4ee54DlEBT4NoYiNdNZtrcy9ESl0hGldAYCEeA1Aj3/0tyJcZXiqFL6FPIqjMuBR/M0nA84rgMCIBVe5PeZESGSkA4PAL6ZoHIC@K6YagqjSTDL@ZfhPTAeewU@97plZjqkue2bSV/7@QTxbiNlIB41IH2omhwwZNZlntm/INCpzxNjuFBQckOo6Zw5LrBC2wV@Z@kmVjuV0lJGO22DwU6DcVx7Pk4H@gGsx7O7YmegTJ5ercKXJJLJblT/XGcyB7eAXhCI22UHW6zmGZ8cn0KhdZ2CbnpFmaC7zxPDVDsP/SIQQlZN9p@MJgr8hi6uxCJrTFYq67TZ@nLzdTuA@x2Ql3LRN2x6RPONxAfVfcEXSA3vygR6OE07npdGdJG@HiR8Y8JMdm92TxOHYD8Sp1V0GPKwL8j@EDkGCYZ6z0BzJeDmK0p1Jgj6ZMXRGzgCkvqknC5j6CviDBWwskD4eU1nSTEeVthL5zAT1kkQ3rSf9pJ@8d1L2iZbQk2F6bRnAEjLSzL2KY8SsuyK79trseLIgv6P3L@9RtLxHN5eXtPCrZeaqeY0Hvl/W2cQCAkRcFCN7ezGw6sC3eteKs1SU0BvlKp7gnYvYo21mPSzpLkTd9aPLfaCPdPjmwVtY8M/W4f/mBgyS779r8@nQ7dnRHPjNCHdsJuijb16wpJqA6AdJ5D3XswtJ@/475gVx8XubD1CEADGWGJeNdpehY45B7fbCCeQA8C00jzu7rtE9bfeq8cAVZXJP0@xEW99E99s9w9LnRi/hx0xH4AY1fgoKG/Grd6s4Mjpieg7X9RIwdiXDUBjGEek8UmUNyejp02RyPVnxKGZIPTRTTiU8WI8/DL/GmnGKr8Znq0EPiMdjOB17auL053g@nnPT/hb/4pfPR/n4w1sSrUbcjhDAAx891fQi2@RN7PNpIqzSO4wIYVx5ucpoeTuAiMaYrrfh@6Ho9ppC40YS1YJWFpY/arO6xc2bWjxCFQFN8sWodyPJ24junWkuQmoc2IKF7b3fEHINMu4D6XYTUYjc58YWc@xrPAH9aJ7OXjOqtFcw1DAlcbqJSeo2yRdJATXjA3jihNNn8ESAA2PS5gQV1A3ntPyPaDIKGenjiNTi@4CQDlAiWOQo94sRiSUEboh@fhnm2V2bZ/dant2lPMMesJxlJJLQXcrSbwVsnpuawDL6kzXcGYNQd4bHTWwbLtvRXZytOI@b8YqZZvHTeAUYctyIV/YTwJTjvXjlPjm8eOWIHCfxyifgWPSt@MX/2923rbWRLOleo6dIS7hRmVJJwgZjhLAFCFtrYfBwsNsbaHUhlUBtnVolDmrb/c3MxX6BPffzCPtV5h3maj/F2vFHZFZlSQLj7rX3mm/Wt9qUqjIjIyMjIyMz47CwZqYFCgzpJz@8wnstwvG7sbC2lXW@pkb@pyA07XoLa9GYUpmX8pMpQqRAv0lrxBVbr6@7ORoGtLCxUukqcEzoYvvE5zAu/1eg/0uaKk5gg48443zChdWiKiYWDWvFkHZo2TAJEmbM5DW9mlf3d9iOKiqCZhZpj2fXYfCkhmcWksJIEMNXvtGgv4Qg5ObabIyUtZI9EB3dOnEoD3Kyfaaex/pAM8vfT6jwWdwI5ybT9c14JUHIAD4MT1S@C88pdExzjBHuZJ0ZaIGoPy/c0ymMdRIXPfr2CPFZd7IQYZszRWSUGKwl00mH48s5NDboD5JMwl9hrN@26/ChnExKcO9ENZYKembe8Zlf655BMNiT37mvO1Y9oJYQQfh4UjiTWRatCyyL8SmWdZamKpOPULBkDs3woPGJ875t60cuJ@LG5bXirmXI1JUmWXIlxSRV9hAF68ofSevR5rWK2Fjft301NW9x1pIFAKtm1IrI1/536O990d@NQm2IMNHALMV69lI6rV7fu8pOYN6Jm50eQHx01bYzUzmKWohJTrsDSzO/j9emVHyYfIiSL41G0Ce0fUO2aE/wDbpN7i0EFrSE4XXy5aclevlp6W5CTWsknWvPKC0eWtJwpOMRpnHX7sdVOj5riPGFz7f9zncP8DA5wPbgAR53YDhBcpnlw6seW7nEc5vEtryBSC2uKRHkfF0aDXP8ksQ9X91G17b0Yr9@sL2/t/uRFt3nz587eo0ex/hh1uKsNVrHBTIbZUfrwYxty5KL5Ey47MZxfHjZH44enfbSU7JEhDUpAz61YthPz3FHyzJLnk/MXaonZS2Kalif4mngJ6QSVB0fS3Zb03VEBAlG2Se@BmLUW6K3y7s1h9MQ1es9vxvU67x8mQTAehXD0JgbcedvmUf5q3DIiW4lh9ZNKsXhKNT2vvrwpnKkjt5U1c7x1l/Vx/1j9aGyd4RIBO@ON3drW4r@q@4dVlUqYXyJfIPYUBJdt4NGgCSyaqlQeKYY8lZ/MBa5k91y5P2h31Vv@o0A11Trod99dSk/vF4w2pBaVdqOjnGG2eb8kt32CPYWnBCRtrFQbprsYAgvAkVlz2lP28Wet9tvtlttKpvC3nfQDkLjk6Y6bRpBkrfGLdsVJQm5D9l0iHOawgLrhqr7VB53NwTGF/srkBglJFli01OacNH/vpuCR9WDt4cKQS229ve2a0e1/b1DtbN/QD/ffaztvSZ61g6PDmqbx/jEBd/ub9d2alsVfiEIFDyFaBO/XIWje1HwUJyp0viEm29vQMMf/UqeekODVzc@u1qGauGqB@nT9jvt34LmQil1FUJ9gXsnXxWo7Hzl4PV7WvNV8CtuOM1VMNsfpI9Dzsc5X1Dr3BpNlg2abyU9XWnZyxUdvo/ojhVS8gQljkKR5WdXGeBsxNNsByq9BRsVnH1LsAqeywY0NfSIYAOUMVgpK06ltbDgrjPIDWqt0ekjsqi0JkaE@geqvjKmJqUUU0zbygAo/CRqPZwHFUvRC@J7erGkmx0NpYB6Gr2QAuqZvIAqWoPtiFrWJa5G@1cQz2pFXvzSHezwtbB6Hr3Y9HkXu6pxknHjIfVVlIoQoTs6nDBNTnk4qStnB@cqIZdHMrFORyZGIGksSSbKVSLbtlHJNAmbFq4atNmbZIfGV@IG2An5rVGosmXHU0cwDgp6bUlVd9Hxe2ICFZvuMO@pVURJKmtP7naU4o09TwZ9ZkCkl0ziEdXb1lph8NB6VHNzqkVf20hymlVjgvYtBDanEPgjYAhQLrHTafBKxd6vANNvaVbOhn3iSJzb/m6XJ3ZuXjWCRAVttZX9pf3bb44mspvYJxk7RcaOhui3YEhqJV9ltvpDmuMsVjkpFqRg47I/GLVlDLPJHvCNEy9zVBoLG7X2c3kj0RroMNlir9@zGj0nLr6j1XNiyoe0yhwvd@eR@IqzJRPn0yIsdndAxz/vXwfW3ZmLS6SbAMcvpAjzXTkOP8cjxkT0z1QsO35XSLK6Wt7Y3jzN/f6zi0yrIhYk0bExOsR/xJhoi6YH3/OxweIQepeeaSZDXnh1jtraBk9LS8xyA4z2gZdt2te9qpeib2JuPP0eXjmT7/nlly9lqZWDZNLZscPLbCzdXHVimnS5zpnSJiCW7CRkSdZnzRuXYUby@hU8cTAKCPvTgxzBvn0i/5wWIaZ351ctkiw6DbAe7gi@ozbYoiLOoQ4PG3s88j9lN8uLG04@NihRFjmzRkS7BnLRcSyzFF6vpsBt3w@O5PfDwa3ei50sD98FbfteaN@FW27xbliyLFmwHg7293vAyuL2h8BS3927AcsiOQ0t4vSIOd35TGRNe3@LP0@NHc89AoO1FycoEVCrtaseX1GbON1ZqeDYYGKF6PBou3pwoNKyP6G6JPewZWhqMQjYj9S72Nq23WNh50VKU7RZjpQn8yZh0Rb5PN0zmWcS7w5RoXUQV9MjEhZxNPBW@1aknl5ZWIVg63sWiIZySew@GxkUnmjAX2kPSMjGg2Z1MDWzmxlZfNqhbQSu6eaKbmzb8LOFtazdSK47HNuAbJsg/wKeJbPH74Pox2umHVGwECsJHW6SJk3rDe0TDqnhARX0vOQI3jMsZkhhZC8KdsbQDoZfhaSG/ecZihlJlHDRhS2xrpVjjZrox/NGzWGDRCwDPiw99UexaKYPRsTzm3V7QJ140csmlyBSMpFu9ZXNFVT97Ktewpga0TpZjhRye67NMzYnBssznM5q2KW7Cz2GLfTKpHiYbIqk7b1N5f4@TckqkWjJ0HxmZ8xHgryyvPz0W7Ane2Gq5/4sbFlDJuXnqDug/X0MMhyHfLxPnFvbc833mAHuIZ2Y1psJM1GRVJ0Za0qi77wY2fgRLnIuRMgguD0y2E626qjbCdxmQ5cVyYbORab6YE3hqKMya6ao//X@5iCQv9neo@9vTyYbCsF08Cus8t/2h2EQe@VZoWGsV3CpT74LhsMeFxN/pi6gZNmN6V5nO/a2E4NX6RU@8n2b3ZOW9k4Ss1vXnDVwI3y86CFpNU73SpPHe7liye7qTm23qp5wsMtW4iwyPUw7lux51O7dhwDLYD6XwPLBPnyPwzX6j3BwDUgiE3vzZZk2zjdxY4qQ1nzC2Y@0WaiWrcXJ0W@FDb@HYCJu@nGo0u4PVJFPYav7O86sk/VCKVGfkAsHvSzVctM5L81V6R0OdAEpCUJGE@@tBQueGsZSEu41F33YR@FiK7iV0zO2nPTzxdXCyosU967njtzuyYsz90mjnFa0@Pq9bng1vGl@uuhfXrdURw1@Ob9tjH/7VanlZ@optbX0g0QcLq6U8xzk9Tn9u6peFJhzNYIvOXoykih7kl1WqQUV78NLj5TDD7xpXoOHxASXqiddw4VwsRuVuycrZ@VeuVDqnvTOSnDyGy2WR4vFxSxe/ECrKMkYuZk/GZ1hTbVPXYPetUJcT85iql1DFLuG0Ju3/rDd363svU6cxkEBwBGYtvXmA3VJWD0Hazb4nni94Carj8lcBY5NQUFKzbFXUBEe83yejOOYZpswo1FxSZsNb/nfsZOaK3hXg1Gfv5gojmAt9aX9JTVn3JgKfKJARU7aJtYj/AsITlwmi4sheTsWK@pcUdS1InwnHQvECWqyOEyfptPwKQSi2pfr5CwVeoHfuAQSyND@haup9XXO106sFnp8igdTDn/IDhOFMzziAoT@DPi2AU2w5h6y20eKuo/fRTzIGz6jGrGfDBvIp1hTxBeYf6vP7N/E9deJAEL4OdG5PH3EqTUvUiTFd5APFxAiLbnxxzUD3CplUObQWcCW9soxcLYUZxqhWU0mej93A3IKreh/uge5Iv@a6kZU3pHiTBK@p9a/QtCSh5Q/beBPJ66WtarlTDVT2CLF3DepgZMu2h69DWhajdVW0OkQ0kKLuZgceGT/Xt3@YtR@eII2zyLk5Xtu6nsu8d2T74JUXMqjBT4utGYXSmc@x@W@qnRczJ1qq6xYefFopBseqSRx2dJ9ZUNv1K@348Ib0VAKV0Yf1hMfctaXn2aMvnx5lKgTMXj0/US@a/5e0iMfYZko@yrZPv6m9AAFbDyrbU0muNTrtTsvUzq5t/4CNksTNZWS6py0UZlJVdY@mFqckAaHc36ethvlGMpi0UgcnjPpjfVXaU8rGS@zk2iIF@PUxJoxRywqcZuLTLhbdlikdvjzIwsEwwSjKTNzN0zlsa48tsCi1CPTrHhBTk1w6trkFC/DL/IL/jGTPYmcKZeZ/XFOML@Vzot3c5JALHQfpWeTKSlN4C4iL3Wn7llF4rbHkxBnC4k96xQ4ajMQH@wWjsEfRXLCFhRGUkzRPfqiKR0XKBr2vWsI8fFr6m/5J6nXPunYg05wqyrYZvjshZVKOLiPgnAUIpwUR7oJrwaDDm4dWeG7YRdqHUR/aRnXLTFEa2X3UjVY9kh5F0/aIZ0qeWofkG9gIBJ/CK8uLuBMBg/Y/g1EK05c2iMvVemN5UCD5szTJXEzDxSCb7AA7rQvbCRk5GT2gNLhwG8EXop0tJC0n5R0tdXWqU75PB1@I4haRkvaWir1T1ftxqet17jPfV4sPC1aJLvW18EF7@mz2MGKiGQ@LCHw4HLxWSpl3Q035G44B4Cu2sVC/554M7gOer0gVaEVgwuGpLSGwfA6aHqp1EEQXQIDLlgZN5Pww@5fDRtyuENKl0/MCC/h0JXrMOIw/MX6LNfFDb4rc1O4tIpvm2mor9tNENB4nLT6uB3mCwuECRB6oFI3GBFRnjgqiRLfPWtcWHfp4iCKqIE4J9bdRESGXn/UbtDI8ElWqkOg5BokbqzXnMCE2mt0fDgHe7MQgHtMTAGDgLlKug@HlL40/y4clO6YuWP3zcjkSfr1ea7QdA@GbZK@MYF5VLiahTsN8NGb2qE63N85@lA5qCp6fnew/762Xd1Wmx/5jhsX5Ry/V73Z3yXpEt2my635Pr1IVw6pZpo/pCp7H1X1x3cH1cNDtX@gam/f7dYIGoE/qOwd1aqHrqrtbe0eb/PtO0FQe/tHarf2tnZExY72XW7VVEvF9dT@jnpbPdh6Qz8rm7Xd2tFHbnGndrSHxnCrX1HvKgdHta3j3cqBend88G7/sKrQsdR27XBrt1J7W932qH1qU1XfV/eO1OGbyu7uREf3P@xVDxQbCVi93KwSlpVN2sKiJe7ndu2gunWEDsVPW0Q8QnDXVYfvqls1PFR/rFJ3KgcfXQ30sPpPx1SIPqrtytvKa@pcKvsNqtC4bB0fVBFBCZQ4PN48PKodHR9V1ev9/W2m9WH14H1tq3pYUqnd/UMm2PFh1VVIxMhNEwyiFn2n583jwxrTrbZ3RGvG8TvYOzg0yB@IMIRlhapuM4FhBoHeEpH2Dz4CKujAA@CqD2@q9P4ANGVqVUAFWFRsHdnFqEEi4pHdTbVXfb1be13d26ri8z7AfKgdVh0asNohCtRgkPGRWIcaPeZeY5wIL3kkZk0ZznV5OFVtR1W239eAuS5NHHBY09zCZNt6o2nuIcSvdYjS7uPMwO/aByut6VfXAYJaTp/IzD6jiSImbe1vV2lF1sGu0vGHY1p1VidCKdnfaKWJPtLPRMiaZnB@dVFv91p9@JhG1eTgoxteuEgv5CA3y2nqnixb@nyFK2Qy9fr7Sp02uof1uuM@pGYCjW/V0Mfg95VydB@RuwE7bxz8rK0J3dcThNr4QV90sqEeLiBQUqj/g5i@@d3AUfl8M9DV4LwPwOboKJRrk0tcpZBoZGdHJJWJm@STCf7d1uzAFbMGvNeo45wUlpFcqB/SP70v8Q9ZHKwXJJ3luCufxyaW0Wj/FphmpBEOicD/6IgE7RY36YVB8OkiW7Cbw57fu@j3m1nHMXW47Ij2gRdZ5xvVz4OLieq5yfqMLF8767QHodl3swoT3T9rkik9Lt6Qe5bFP/UR/3EMNhLzAaem3BQfVutDy@wPUh0WSa7SoS3gXsGDDJ3vbeXH2gfs5gpLz0oT799E72VuwV4Q4W9pwTvhemf8582ZFKAJxrE4iCRtHSEjn7fqGHuTqPANFbxEoZt2E5Y/tFZfBryuE0lIkb3yO3abWI2H7Vsbe5LDrw8qbzePd3ZIdALbZ6vLz1dKqSjs1o@u/P2IdjhCLUcdG9A6Tnoaf7JmyRYpPjxTrADhMfszA@fzKIi472bQ@CXiPER2G0lLJggydDdEhqUeTPTSAeiQVhyA41HK8OvMmakZIJvoqoPedP1bVvF90pWYB7QxS2fMo3aLfwA7mv5mikcd0gykWYxj9hLn0u6C5V56x5iK8uaGA/egiJc2fCxh3CIa8FEX28/Cu5Z/ad62RjEUU0bMVx52rklIPJrEQhm7ip7M7HccZ0QfAHP0MHrzo@Y3evyoA9xxuDs/HFVGh0TGnagmzqnjw2jd6RMN@Qx5OBBUzbS0rnDK72ikeO7p4@QoMIg1GxgVJJWBjW8ScCmKIzLZJFvAvlpw1GfhVATvAJyS5lj9mzh3Vnc0lJKJH6J/m6gUSmBFQU6EajdRGylT5GMUx8KQM0GmP0UPhv8PpMkM@Ou04yToMbWsIIAPoiRDFVrR9pWJ0r4xFw3W7UZMTfvVxxjMV3tgLqOO6dubW/GvIRLo0RmbFx857GErO4MAYHIcbNjzNzJJu/Rp6/Qq7ejquCfpNbqDrNJrhVkqpuDmVs5cVrtcc7eCH45y5KzJanCXqqpXsnE751lPW6aJrbx6HKYFnGPif@Sf8AFINOGZSy/FanWSswp6lhk5oEMtWQtOM4qYRGrp1ztv7Z4oK0RmQvbrmy9DKAK9AXym@8kJSfpKzHOTERd5JVZHHAUPccixTcbio0PWnbMhZicAnMdNPgxBzpLRDRaIjkDnUH0xNJV9zIYiaCS2OozjDELcOh6RlpfVmwh7PpkEh0bYH/ckBH4gp1qmhCcBPjSGtru8p976Y0K587BuC4vlnxz2XdguojE5ltD1kZ@l0e8PSXX00W/C0W2PHU990IcOQS@8Gur4hbSetYf6RMIo/dQM1CbZvfMyI7HnGbWwPYK3QtNj/uAudQNYiEp4ktvcisoS8xoe3TCHju3bxaLKrsdf1okmHJaUibiuVtSXL1JKCKpDhgZMwXYYbS7YZpPbwb1DNP1u@sNPWPuhAvWaQTOKTGqB5LNAGaRaj2M8NkbS9UE/5BMNGgqcgESUKMpBWmSoSmv0c81O2q4pHUfHROxS7sn3txMxqbGWooZixtWtE/Ot5GgwQaUlHRo0ChZaXFpmVGZtuL7euRnjaKHJa2uVPu1FImVNlIjyY6M64knkZvT0EU/6kL/8OMTsoTe449YqKBCGzop71Wk5x/jBpuBDOxg27TNR0mSa/gDHb7z16feYF83RoQ771/BHYTCmHUAj377NM4x69i/9y159q9/xL9r9tk/7NASOvxWJh8cxP2LALob9m5BTD/GHplWoOY6fJb6MhGHD7@hesmSF5gpHwSBrmymMhuPKpYSJ4JNzGAHGaU@ZvweTMdKiOs@W40qppP8p2@MVndKddZ8WZ1WWG30A0AJuY8KCQnxIR@yYZDmflqYKnN9XwMLxXOWU79xhsZfA@AWRiK9hEhgbZKbMEuxOYGd2J8YnzVu3yTEIhwi0FGwHyKQTZvm16yOTNEmRl7AUWFPF1YJVVW5RbhGHEA/ju8m99PwfjD0h8CfQLz6dxS2zGIFFXMtEWwplv6KjjBIubB7YZhnNkpikWPui3bPcDzltxe0k1OTn8V3UYMsfUop0mL0prsSMzNLGBxnysnUSOfWxg0VlQS04HLcDKkhllC3czbDBt@xnefLjEldOziCYtjTkrIX0XaRqEJWQq3fCvNZGWWIqf3vGLC09dNQmCFieZXJm5YzOpo3mwh4obVlfca3VH5IwTk9QT5t6LISj/mDhgdS7U3bMjMw2i9YNx/mmIbAwW5kWyydNJm15jMdxKTWJzwTTJCnGlmbEQ9i@8nPE5pNEvC3XMd/K9fE36HAXzWK7qWhRica7KXMfi@I1LHrNQhNNKcYdQUpL0fuTOnW8frcE0TBle1VniVGHyKiP5dECNUGmiEoPpxBzn8Z9gh5NohzabRLt7PG5k6iTRnIm5Kn5lAhyCXoicDucNkkuDVowvkCYONFwIyEVKZy37piv8oq5cwQZxgcBCK04yMXnUHKCGw/WBB9xdoBWtg5roSIkET1t2BYOUdD/iGAclV8f7miLh/o4VzwrCaTbCBLtKrjUfZCMvzn9PKnfMpQpUtAUn0GKqEdTsuny4b36s32hcgRBavNnbelbcNEZRy0SNvSP/al@Cx04bkrXTMyo5ESos2iguUC7lItOINtVaH/toXA8rBv0NKINhLzO4s@iroFw3iuFiNqoctsco4ijyS2zzVG5DakSM5T8Bvn1VBRVlzeuBCAQjKl@uUgQENaUscelAIfesTkvgageI6pYLmJa0kuOihrbec74DqLqAs@WrRKFWSVe2DByM4GQYjG7TIwI6Syzi8RQaKGbiYtV4vns/sQlSCE2vC8Up6HQo5KkYTRyQkBOUl1wYolyUlRuQXMwf3y27CQ@RvzNX18UrK@Fya9EnwjDk1xx8utqIfE10ezSUrJqoibRw7FbTXwkUjg2wpFU@HP/Y9cUO@R5ZBNqbTISWoa2z0YScdpl0r7N@yVU6@yUbXQMA8/2DDfbr7qkWEkEZb8/ALta4CsDxG7/0701lqkGE50rgOPSGWeXrGwIWWNNY6lHt7DTNZH2ogAFZk/bb6n3Rzs7ibCv52NjaNQNhsuFQgFMfG4Hvze21ThKavfzydL51lWnkx/c/GX4/jzPsj8IOCXAmtlBBzQkNClCrz@8kMwQwIGKonROO7Jir3/VatkpGHBDicGjYZOSOhqC4gWoHRm9vD/iAyAGqRfYn9FB9O9nFc2@G18UTQ3FXENRbZgEX6fN7RmRBy9asM@ObqoYGASzsWaidcspb3zGCoLMJjxYHL7Y@RybJ6ffBJ1O31UfkLwYkQLmvk5W2NmxKxSkCG4Y2bv3KuR4tK4Krtsdy68YRWxeBzizMJk8EyYuPGLjHwQX1dtBNn3yU5qWFeryIrq5iPjUrkpfpB0dLP4BYIUPCe0Hle76g2yD6TRZmJZ6PYPjJ8LoadGdufdJFHH4TEzT7NulQdTZ6HocrIG67rAuYGLZ8/ByT@4oHhE3fXpbbIGGBYGhcULMlYfVgKvZP04sXo9arYdJRU4DIAP7XRJRMqH8OYHIdwA8A/X0I3oiivZfczStdyYCioiCg2Qd03IHFeqokEo9bpR/vclWKhU1P1hcVJXKJj3kcqqyWVHbeLG5qbbp9yZ@/1BeWl4uiczddj7Ty03z8qvaJBh8wrnYuBxu00/6VobfGKy1McTz@fK8W5qvl9c3SmH@pLIJt356@s9/@Z//@a//K1/RP/4dPzb5x8lPUSHP8/Lzjc/zP3wt4ffJ9tnC/PnJ/OBs4aIELvsbRw3v10Y5PzYf9YbnqYysAtZbtiM1@2yOPqOrKpM3sOsPP5F0WVOZRpjP6LehZI5iGZtpBNb7AH6U57SFN0kHJrfyhESGgI5xHE@j0whggEfrDVGScIEdqNSXuxVzcI9wMFGB6FYloyPxsM56HcCnJY6kAF9cWrFy7V4Y9HACfs06r3QvlfLpb3tU1/yb/@lteLHZv1VPTrPqSUE9cdWTdJr/FFde0FtnPt@Gd64Uo@1AOu3Sl/hqAWaGKmyzosf7B861M0HuVGqeU/YAkglTwYXFC86Ndn/sLCMJ18KL1BySdyo5IuFLJlTJfJ7vfaVh@UwlvqYTrjasKNT1LoYbs25UovGFCuSHYggQt9wVgqz1qUnc9LFHMp7y5o0e6xRnE2LAIOvB6x2e93hBa9F8T9s8J/ZSSHPE5vPyFmtjSZyhGW18kfZjBPhCRbaTBfYkXMgspMTK2@old1O8sO3@aeYTW4dxMDK26VLpd2UxgVhz24Sb72m/Fm3ILdcrKt2OrlesptKTtt8qZVXpXnVG7YF2V@DWMaE@R619lZmEEWVAAkdi9q9NzzA@KDCRoiaGRZJljVWzj67LTOhp13QaYMeTmyOLCPmfsjS3v0zMbSfPXiKGHYQHGKnIlK/ltzuhjroyZGJf@MNzZAf0W5xQbST3ZnyehySsExj3WxHSHkNmk/N4PlNXMoOhf9H1XZXZ6x8N/XGNli3SfEYNz6EeIgQTkMDk003P6p5BWHqkh4QpEnWFLYeQvKAz1unRZGzTkc8JhtRMBR12BZMgwU5MyeBLYqwm6Bhz9XcMgo3ylPCObiO1iGXJC0sjDSltu83wNJuaOinTgj13oomTTgmq0cw0vKArXWGh7fLFL0nyDmIE6LbT2gtQuyKsvED7WJ0ugp6fWJwGnZRx9M@XlKyLmM@cilKskVIayvNinPEOWJEe@VMyCoSsTSacUWoum507DXU6t4y9jnCQ78gWP@@rdpSAjhOYsWeIOu61RVhOrFBxDgxP1djynyC0Ov4F4Te@8cdgxdNM9uWjvHPy02nv7En2tPfl9DeHMdEi2ayyOZXRl9lGYum5Qitj3k38NFZpoQk1eNpLFjjtKfFhsUhAiOSzJz/lz77kCaHTDLLZn2aEIIkhAyb5@9vLA3x@Cs1MEot8JjXnPHHM4GdfFh1Fayv/xRjKC0f@EhZmU8nH9LTPGbYIFPvp/nolLidhfnWp8Gyp@Ix2QhfBbW4YXGG9zYVX58EtqRIhtrO09Jz@luCGBCG@3oZ@iV7eUj8lrYn4noTaSUmLUD3NuZ1UxFZUxxOeoPJEZQ6XChcXJyrj4/IRG35XEcuZshwLSkwHLe7LYv0M@12044eQa5PeIcKRsDIQGxE@Qs0Bskm@cheHOma6LLCfk6e2ELuVgdDw5jPWatHr93JaWXO8hRKUaHjNdFYLq4XJOTo1RRMzdF4rUwuPVHHj5fP/@Lf9XzOjzMZS/sOQ/o4yv2ZWVjPySA/066n5dZ3ZyKyj2MrXzDhPe2B6fP4f/5vqb/yF4ODLeJ3@2Vg2sFbGmY1cmat8yWys0ENxaYna/T///M/Uh3nZsSEX63zdVYxYyVBky@8x79J3VUMvZVu6EIsVdswCDLEwpL05/YBh1O3SaoGP6TLaquI60JGvjD2KXuLZMGvEpkJykmHsKUgzkgplNJATkMaEoqUs2w1jtgHmjdFUPz/2VkLaAfyszTmiJiPTjcchTIbmZVtEA5iVFmk/Lw8bhZfpyLxjLW1sSkpGhcTWTsva1aclYod3/WDUbiStJMx07Tb8m@DcAx96QfOK9lS9sNP/ZZi/JpbsFpdW8y0c7ufZjjs/YEi5wdj7jRRBnQyINoZsdOqqIY1Av4sQXi5nCyKFfie6kzL5JEnLHgQNOcNK5iSmIuLj58r1MLrjxap0lv8lBR6ZM3UiSCtX2mmPau4frKn0YlRQyvGe1wE279g4VofAyIk17IBlk5fiPuB00PTHqwwv2AmJayHquhTx/Gaz7utv2dRc2qRKc1Nzl0FnUE63JLw7YqfixkTTX9TMO6Hk2jhByOVY0AFWNxj5tEUvp/kN9uNxCwiTou9ao1BxMVlbuqze1TfLnHXlnqZvpOkbGlFoCXE7Ec9Y0diUXUxkSxlHlcOgjiu1mQ1Ta6FJ2jz0@A8wCGVYai24JejusAckUS3ujrYqs4fN5b0w8chNID57crQomatTmdj50TUlxIMauhPa9aQxEhCIgrsGC2X6fSgeEGWTZrTdS0k8v4nPJr6HBsN92EcoUTtsnQQflWWpd43cN@0R@1IqIoGOK2vbYKdk9YhARyG2ohS0aRy8pB2wVGuNN1tc0AzHGqeBNiGh0mk5pzppqCi9bEtnr5VEEfQiXSguPX22vPJ89QWynM3p3s4Gg0oedgGDS59gsEadpU023pfL6YW0vEIK6ukmAX0WWFzAwazrxnFM2Ocb51G5WNDACmmGdcNpNKS6Pq5kkDHEYeBhRaA9SnaYzmZfrp2gY2enTecL/Uf8beIDMsOZcLS@kN4ah3dxZKpUVwIOlFkwc1Cc7FNEUHH0F7ts0G8dINpEAFtXYXtqaBcRIEaXw/7VxaXNHZ4ObXVEE4YIznGpsYN6HYziAGMWVtBF9YFDzfK@KBt4J9M9gFEulgTofAKcppmOW@lrS1PMjgVahBBZEx6ruEK0TEdtdmbu7PVVdW97ErGMnYaO4Xq2ZSspdxzJDAFkkKvX6u4RUVdHu2BXUi2T3ERUZRZwBZQrsju8D1/pBhJRW1Qxspr1hlH2PrIUmRfj0KZxVRpH4DUDZrHwbVIav1bTCxDECEJ9mhQJMTe6z7FJFuNkDzLmKXg5vWbZiL5thyEHmNONpR1tUcqFOKvAXOoOgDi3KaSlI4U1jCg/Vjnxsow2kjmKVzSOBrQZcrRTDWaW5DQTbHUbSgBsZB03tED/a3tbrtqu0j87H7ZdKMqblb@i31GK57vxLWp8i2uqtmOGwI4Wyza3sJn6FS5KxCwFHTA2RhDCtyVZEYM4akC1tqNpL5P6JDG3z2KuALv6Wgk3p6N6kiDQC5@BzOnNexSKg911@N2aHF5NS5oopIqeFnLEdf/EtmgyF7caQRJSPgDE0iSIKFBLzO1zMcOLBTpr3r7euxjGru3M5ukEy8qGitT2nTyRPcmzd1LmPrZY0myxtIZxvI8vmG/v5Y3zoNXXvmgRc3yDNx79Md7IPZw5cv8tmKP6j@GOp5o7nq5B9gh3RGHD2aOT07D3Z3DM@ZjX4HqzfdHG@VDL@olOFFwLAAs8YAgfUvpYLKBvd4gTlZ39YXFyPYKR0NIyHAP@UOef6c4/W4PM5cft4L9q53N/584v684vr2GtmTHyWrWzwq3/fXocq4TZ5IuZwwt1V4o5f7SnK7qnK2tYTWcM8//3nub@H/X0ue7p8zVETJALBwlffz83iyZSOdyq1WJzCy@lg3Zlkcd@Nlc62Hs1y2naPLQ6V@FlGdq6@sP4r2r8VyGN@Alp6HAXEdmGRnt52Z6Ks7xolnzKoeBkJT2R/prI6FZ/9YIV70f0AiVCmg@2hnqjQgq5Kx/j2yYv1h9j6RstPg/FWWS7TpaJi3NrAy07wqITT3HRfHWSzKWVaF3Z5hjIauvoYHfxfwgZuv4n7YVGyGNob4JOx6wk9hbsKIo6pTtjdQewD/WeI8EqmpyM7Eh7e0fsMne3VOPAFhPr4uxNgly14f6P9lJd6BtWVm4cGRFtPF3f7Kpgmmu2F/KG@i6FZndZ9/gPcekLzaUv1tSB3hjcRSpfH/hpXoz3aUvLy/etAVLLwx9MwIJL5e@ZVf8X)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/8tzxr)

Berry has `#` line comments and non-nesting `#- -#` [block comments](https://github.com/berry-lang/berry/wiki/Chapter-1#comment), like Zephyr. `1/2` is `0` in Berry, unlike Zephyr:

```
print(365-((1/2)*380))
```

External parens are for Berry, internal parens are for Zephyr.

Answer (score 3):

## 366. Befunge-98 ([Rc/Funge-98 V2](http://www.rcfunge98.com/v2.html)), 16128 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"93"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'@,,,"285"z;@,,,"366";k09<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;@,,,"364_";# _'1:,,@9
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@PadSD4o8vI/BFXoF6TFAmAAL9JkWq1Wv1advdTW1K/92KSzQZJkEQLBNgAKZEtqcv27HrjJDOb8ThTjpPJczybWWczVZOd2tk4O8lMVbI/TqXmp/wBnY@trdRW/B94zzkXAEGJlLqdSdXU1kIicHE/zr333HPPPed@HHR0b/izn8XwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nuJx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@8w03N71FBr79OTRo@u@WfZVybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrpwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//kYZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@w1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79kvsoEBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmNfAVXheulQfUCiGZ1Cv6a3KhvA8C1JcJfQj0qCAYqMAboLcgZ0QtAyy@VeR2eXwD1cJs32uCoSqCSqnAvzMuxemJePCCxLtL4yz8Jzu@SQIqMa1gCjU81pkFhC4HtighKK4KEo/tiKHiTt8TCSa7jn1KZ5OJbgokiSXYTCLwwACSqMCcKH2TUnbV9cuXcvEFw2ajUgNpCmgG32klGNNpiwlIFTQ2SZpBE/E3niHE@wbySSUF@MfMVLA2ITUGqtzi4mQxd6HL1fCRAJ0CrYSMkBYv12/sQ8nfauN7SNnhhJxF4HQpPZnYhVAQZ/3htqt2E1voRV0HrjiFUkXkxPoG8QL/lig4p@NNfwUPyt@UWJtHACS@DT6koU8aS@34Kg9@ZdyxcJuAs6O@dGHSj@qT@RFTKitC8TBJ32Rk/lQLA7cDjs2e7J45rfF3mg0jHtypKH5XR1i7w3MboYpH1y8OBo9@gX2ytgWGanct1DMXOlAg6105k0sKdKTtYqm1EYC8AP27fDxoTLcUTBD2aSM4uISvMuDC6zAJ2HR1@9jhKQhBAdlAO48XdNpOFxQOgSOro3vDYIs0EqBVmGSYK4TDpgAczQgUXHcD0oz7PpmzfYeNcLNfb9sWTWVOcAAk/lwA7SyRh4TQALgjp9PiJSWpBCTRsXGhauaMygPB@j1Hy9MCRKR0jm48NH@0c1AuvPq0kURfEmIEvpbk8GmremoIKvigPsD1xdlpIXBUd5msq6EsHd7hKCF23L1sAHAKjryA6TrFFQNW8IZd@7XjfylbohBdA7QbguV0bloe6HFjRSDhziuqjyrhpFKWAxWIVeK0esMHR52Orm80YxV44OW91Fnr0oUFoUgHEgkBtdCDr1JPSRF1KkL1b7xT9@cqPgHgmRoApIQck8i8mUl2cJqL1IJot7yh5oaI5lyJ8RxxOZmFSUeLAuIHc9Uj4j8fdn5iSRSfKnmoS4kPvu7oH2MIjsT1nTTAYpDaiL48jk9nF9r@sBjdiO5QwctgVpuHQYZAhi09pq7g4c@0YL6eiJVY3hEiHwX5y40ccw1phvSHGkVFF1lS826rZ3DlxaLWQRSYQhAqVQfPmVfqYDuhb1Pj74@j4MImo@kwndGboABZE0hC50dSO@5MEkyEj2y7OyguFy4Y3eHgRIkfU6rLTP6MKEu4vglZ7EMWVlZfyVRfqKcwPjr5z5NdICH05a4Iig7OCTZ08OPtl/uvt5c6Ll80vvuUy5AIiD/DogC8lDjjfsrVu8a2K1EFwM@oaL3Qu4wBQUlGC1aOq5wLhljCLzAqyhGr7QmviKM7TjXvJ6Zc4xVHpldzkJPcXOx6P6CUHR7lmojLh8tRrHc6Sf4WQy9iqKAr18OO3IoLQqr7qOpQ8USgcDg2UpKqouB4c4r@GtSgGF8eYGT8Ent0B0mNMMom6NHFBeaM0bWQNLcPA0a2WZgyHowrgwbrhJOaRgqo3SAw0BdGUlrBsxYHoD3PrPoJ1ETtpfVrUSp2s1o@UUMYi21P0h7kbfANUpAaMVoCJ57ZU17zXvsTlwaYR0HUiMyVs0yeExHAssBoIkzZqinh8gh7gFzpciryAcvZ7ibC5wKSWfyRXVQl4BtQzUNJBZJZxzk0b6pDuUJo4E8CSnT/MGESrse13d7stbviMoLMh9H0FVs40XzabdAgG9eY/KhuvOjXmrobaSVXYzyZYfP1kF6l2qHtJu4AG0S04gTXqyNfysp99kZz2delePKZPR2B9zpDF7uguC1BsH@HXPiPY9TKBEA5WtpbgKRn6rrJgQsjCpgDfElAIdCkZaID0FyyWB0IviIVAO8K1IAraYzeD14Ps7InwElW6ke9OJe7RGgnINzpZ6Y0AiTTZ3kUt7OD84gdExpHzk0tC4yKTZuRHHeXTd47OVkMhf4w/Sg64WQqBZ@XBG2g53NQARUCpSz4FzAF3htOlwMcuISj9QGmRIZcLJB5AgbFo9GACfgcS8Iru8Ijwn8lmu0qntnNsIrWOwktQxJ3yy35m6uNZt9qJ1g@hZjccBaFS5CF@nRfGO0eWzrDwx1QKUQJ2NjJGDUwkgXRErMKgKOl9QR13Qwxlr6FYZCVcMAb7E7u8BF@safL5IGqESBSS1z@ITV9mVvq7o0hug5ltkK6x8pIn9Rj8JELC8vYFmSfwZUJJOnBFF@ozmWzDwQSDuCrhiCDUGChP1mjM27Os6H9cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0EV8Y2MjXonX42lw7YBrG1076EqBa4dcErkwnowuSpEmF4Y2KAX6teJXjQDyLNlCGpih5PDGHCf0RqWSbaX1huo/NXwmoSkA8xBbwgfAiSdrNXQmk2L9HNdsQH6P1H0Paee465pjHwVfAYGAv/s4yBISQL1Had41qqib3o6RUc0FpdFAETPhxpuNTLPVvGj2Us2reBpTJ6t6DfRDYF6TxEgeuM50DIJbI1eRgLclG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkZ5MflRKpnSO60TcAJpKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQTn6JmgZlpWIyxclyL@TbCVTcUibjKeBLdficcALLTh6VGmcEeBE9MicASqhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb9ujIdzNxohnHUDKRtn0Bd7VXBLD3LxKJd8w9NHBbolTT@Qe3k8EG5x8g7lpfGcc3eBl7SpLO2MCsbdM6k/cia68qkMSpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkpBAOiar91PSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQzB18T4ZTYJbB9rQ0UJU5Fozu0GHxzfsAnYXrPTiU4NKVxBfAAgC9rgw/ZKIoleBiCUgXtKHIBL5IW7FoVkalQnDWE8zN5wvj13KYW5XSsAxmZA5sxzUkQAmkEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQBzXzdWJfwQ2lIQ8XbNIAjPrIcnXDL2XVkPWg8iqQH/RySHBk9wQL@0Qf2KPO2cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNogJ9bC1hr5AYrjjXvyZAZJhQQOuNFArt2B0HnOepqmFbr5fiUIQ6oAZA@hkVArtUHFDYIkFQKTfiPv82mhQEf/5PDhPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U5Epfbzoy7EGa7QM9mbYzMgENQfo3p9aR40y4lg8v62ZmuNJsjqaWTnM@16dlbk3XdTqORVNBtyVdxJ@6nm7pfBIqCN399CnI@s9PjmtyJRJJ0c9Gt@aN85Crs@X4PIiuOdJ6a7A85HHCFDfzIo5bwa5PZDN@QAEDpv6eT2ijwL@I/kGXwjUU37@E/iPc7wmysj@LQK@hpx@xTBFxDyhuePM9L9TMFfqv1cHCeCrF44LjorQXqkb@Z5N@f8k7S96nErIma@GdI2@@F3RJR4wWKc8j4cbQpThRQAWKE@4PXRuvSPH47hY5XFl8Gm5CGBpWsLR4BBILLp/BoG@hXAVKC4rofA@nARL2GFdJiHXj2hvrghDq3ZjPgM42lnhsIbZBHQgGNwVFGmFTYf7cd5W6kO34a5YeZ6sO6Pw0rbJd56vcqFO5XJ1T@Kz8ZhtAbNerwYa7ddEwp3g8jEZQqWyQgqpJC/s3qhpu0/Bosl2gJFXBU0CdmGkZqTkr7rcu44pHaOgzsdmcfZTRPge9BHdLbt5TBkaV9jitwVc1CIn7MmxnziSQ@DAWn7juDoHPsNRsGZXQPlO771g9ia@SAcEwrl9hA/mbFMJdnP5mXcN0gw2ctIOWJ0X@Gtn7eQPutSat34wQ2S0aAoLuc8EuT9Nnl6wBQ96Z7I0tc9JiV/LEaQ/9nVL29X2lXAZ1XX3uCf4elxrbPfr400amxSEIIx1Xvkq8FWfB9mQQnEFQwn3k4MKdOhNzQpIA7UQwsb6qDIWa0SIJFB9g8AyqLMzIrxEW/dK4XNSlb4CmmjCw5N58lGZG8kruW/pkYtic5vjy43p083UiP5saZb/jLzpUWIZWZkAyNTEMilhlxycP94@OZKBcLxHfxxWcCnRHvTsEAWVdpQNMRitfYR/14uwjTJNEtV2ArgbaR9tPD0RdBaIH/QNyR94xMNwEeCZx8aUL3rTeRQm5hOYjCPdbdSeEoxBYwkhCnQhYZWX5n9tc1fLLWQGKTxEmAd2JexXArZmUp7b5WvZgoCG5FaLEubIK40VtM0FcbFNN@hvqRrh0DBoWCY1Qg0aDSW@Ay0FkkbVaVb4HAOKiAuYOELuiSE1Bu9hratD0NfAGkYYg@Mlrb9mLRkYqt1Kbq0DR5jJ/AzqvfwQuQlgG7Rkrs91MUH@/0ZF5GfhaIOfcz0mdvnb6osI2uUPkc84UPdgwRUyH9lct75Na3oUFnQxZCU3FYEUClhDzjwf4NEvhxPlB58Fk5JFIsosQ6RqinF1eEg7ZpsYIh@BSGW@Mq0D7BMb0xIHaPPGPBkSlA@qt/kYS7LNNQQzUrOWVWgzhIrxydk06lc7EaDouHZr2qUPrPaGrnZHVPEqEYerRqXUzJW5CpdtS1LAMPK62rnTeqNOn24oItOzhL6iTB02o@7IwCJG6ckQPmltfkfPyJpKlbP3tqTTSgptJr@@IKZVLFLnf6ZjrogIScF9Y8FwRDZgU0rMm52Q1OGuAUzEwHgHj4trLourX9x@xJbz7@2j953/@Rg/wf7N1hjBQ4Mxj6GjD0I0tJfXXNpafFF/otrph@QT51DJ1Qgy57gLZ1V2okm6FjtWgaRFekmD4H@GSgt/iQJt4A6nxFjLjJecrgsFzdSarFtVsYJnddXGv7cfiWdHyDyh2PUICF4JMgxIR6@KNYMz4EkxExUY2dnehgk1TjIiZt/twOpnyOwiudzaiOcbfbX3Tj5nJ6x3VUPjO9Vua3NVPpz1HGp8OQjm1sCLuova0BiyBOOAvB7fRubr6vIJ8J3jwXBdtMbQp5/S4iyo8e@qNpQ5p4T3@Rh1hdEsOrsXv66KY/uG90LEea6ZFt/ekRB86EIq/G0LBvaZSBGnmNTRbemeOMsjww6ks3FkAHKfWTaUy2TVLy@Px@vSoSVL6cnl16pnc5fhYNUeg8P2sEp9Fowr7O1zvaFUYrsyRbklaL@Jcy8xXbUy4ETVc06Q0ePiCTmDcSuQ4IHWnlu4uXLeQ@KIcwTLCuhlpf9h4ZnYdEAfGTC3KqhYMHZEBg1hmsDVukRFuJ6ZbZPuDuQqNwXESKXStZgFOd4JbRtfQ1HswNL5VEzfERohEdtZhquuc42@t@DAE1ZTfV49ob1aW6j2Yk2R1LR3G8bXDwdLkIE4@3kGo56Zn0G01Yk9XFnTStVb6L3eBYNovOo13F1l7puV47JjutyFo4AIW@H01QUdxaeq2RJPhUfctPCjY47BoUN0aOFahNFB0uK1t9anbR77vP9@Xw4UcSlXv4FCB@OPYqv9cy9dPFff0rgaiA4su7m@NOG8ZYlexKX/tZX3tQDHAhbvVNXuUKVFKWeFTfWsyxiWXc30ePH@OoWMdaoOhYzwncRqkO0xQLoFj4nIR@@fJLXd7br33Y0o3wBbvqkSkcU8tAwYrut9oUqZl1A9MoWYy78@i@tbUmBorFY3DzisDj9XfomS8f6EyfjU2/Zl6XBzAoylhrDe@ZvhepcZxGt9uZSa6ZXaNu0WZZaY2Bul7jKrzM3A8Q8fNFAN7Ol5q1SXtzD66HWXDcdClnd5S6TDkQ/lQ6Q5JaUk@9wz63aoxcQ0PN4jV8plMxhdgIisuSy@3aVLZMO0rk9@XMiafRc6LuLjK5kacq/MgtES3IK5lQdo6xZ4il8uKbdrGZI739@SmHcexPqSlgKnigWEHtFWJttre1mI3xB3/EAlbTF14OOHR6a@btOCjja9bAn5Qab6t0aNLQu/VmhIueo5wQWr59fbpm8gC01254OFWnBPim2@t9bKkPxuiyiW5eGuv4xKq0zEsnT9mhdxt8Mpy9lZ4y0zDX6zFxV2@pLtYio9dY0rjOSDL7IGWMjRGBr3eIuXrPTSR4T/WRpo5@FsXPDOMrjLbN7rrIoxN4As23pfWkCPC0sSxQb@a4D4/1FMs3Enq@67jwMGq30okH4z0gcFtttzGKRcTFribhqt1C@fqqYsK30HThWQLYxzrSQI61akx94LnSoBP511o1@no7um2a52/i3Og79Hb121hvTnE2kNnaA@NId83Hr6t6xxAjxNuY@e2okOpB0PcyjYeL21xj@LTcizrffCJrJEzSsfpryzTPh5@xZNbHwSXn7T3H3dO3ukTzjvQsbbXDI0pjEueM3HGhkRv66JaONHD7@t4aLBI/fPOIN2q5wNGgufPC/9O3XKgO5PxmB7tsTX16EZJJTqzfJfc1OdbU2hTpOMO5DfOqCP7nrK/b4WWwFezmI456Q7x0DinbGPgdLpD865C@4YqlGDKh7@@l@6KmDGZ9BC9ZcsE9LpzGemlFg0/xsfBukb3Z4/4sBY6bpFXVs3Q0bFsaayfdj0@G4ouVsEJ4Uhv5Ie3K3T8vfJ6ak4WQCN7mcLpXb4sgY51Zfd3T6yVrOiMxIIN@7sq1lIpCekokEtGBgQedV22y/vcIl0sm@W3dQWK1pJKFNmX8iHo9vf@0OygGZm3Bf8l@lratLRykLOH04F3k2Hy6foeiGh4Wz9tQXuZI1PWMGbptv9Yh2bNUvCQIzzbIHNNjVvXVPK3LqpQPNWSdMeERxse0HTTtXNoljn2@J1J/bVLcf5eJtDFr68XctzMVyvTfsP0jD5fAkHXXSLiyHFxJzLIIFIXV9JxBh2ZORe8OOOynQEwdclii8hB3HViy8ptQqubPxwzpc8/MQY67rV@Yk5ws@YKqiCSXbW96E7YX5vqnvm1KdRsHbGhxQa@DOlGj/bj2wp4T/WB2X281BBhIX0E@zs9@WOJ/NHrZlucD00PdzSFjlsmppDkOBEj1bVBb1gR8/q8fWisYtGB@DHIlbFXza074zmeFpuT67ZpdXNCs6z@c53quG4T2K2FOJ@OxlPPf6wuA@2Zis5Cj07J3zs3Abj0GlgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFaQwf1BcONdJ4183LWfAvl7KMBDaQAhD4XwF4TyA4fkZbshx7RWUSHm/57InTnRILq/Ya2hbI8sk0zYnt8/mTCa4OSd4YmX4yIEnFJQneJfvfygE6WQ1Rp7cLesvjibfMb4D5R07U7droDO0NxJVC/xcjb1g9zGe6HDQXsp5VEvrOhZ0L3BYK7tM17GnE8md2reOCoVbR4UKWpuKkAFLfG3/6fNklBpot/ZdUmhgj2zhWrth4BqRmTYIYuv56HLsQJd4yO0kHdFW4TvS7KIxpy6x64fOKn3n2RwGkPdWmID5T0cPjS4uG96Z9yfOU8d2YDQaA6McHRn8zP/SRo/VCTHZEzzVDvjp3ZnNMYFdMwhxaUMfGx1oX2vhep@xiAN@qE/0NUMRzQ2S/he67qQV0@oY7iua9Iu416m0ywV6bMxIt1hPMLwPSpNul4vEOB@31EeWVmy8sePY/E7cNgMP9entXAWGArq9/0K5jBvxl@YFVupny1U9POO7RIweN0qxrq6u0XEsfr9lT5Jt8j0BumsanvIEbRyQXyHHJJC@vFt5SPFWHrJQjUCSPdM9WqRfrWosQKqzD9gCNNTdroMrYb7jlt05EcMEd7DpcG8/3zjQAcTPgGPp3alvLPSuYlmjzohuaxWGSGseGR08FdQhax4TfXazMfnMkG/KILKjKzQAELAr7NQFlngG2kjy7mFrSY9axqo5phtx6rXL5bRZR7JNo/tGx1kzh/C1mJteCoc6K5@Qc81cdaQb0SyyotNJ95U9aXnrGgg0liFNhi7o/MrktuntwMzKivWQ6cjAReblVZi1oqvjDamyzur19JC5uobk2/oDXhLa/ePyobS7VvJE8PB/@OArCgzC7UIuMD0CrOvuFXwo/NS1/cf7UOAzx5v0zdkhlBtPAaxjJ1itPCSBB@8Z6NpaVwloPXtq8dmHQWTf1ahH6phEVpglySJ2PTEkwz6TyBDc7GaNHH7oS9lF670Toyf5dhBwpUF6Epz/CqP5zxULqFHeiJs9VYUjdlbI@ds/VyH3POAMIG85E2ns0VMZe88OnhyeyGNPXTk@7Q7xdMQNOW7JsIJWykSmpF7pbmS9k29H65neRHlwrEp7Tw5kjLAG33xFQ4IHrswtPdbOewZWXBV9rRaEocZktYD4@OTpk9TiiCZL7A1dZ2Qko8F7x8dpPGnyleOVwdHUj6B39J3Z2uQH@6qaXEG@z21aHVzHPVfktA7SiQHaKBDjY26X5U7hquuMjd7JfGx8CoMncnDvPbMvrK3kJ/qZOcBeyMprEUUdlZXlQi4Z2ZkNyrbhhs917XlqjpFbdumh8Mfa7SgoOWQVN7taerhtxf@6FMMy/k6ED0ukZm5Sa9SOsKJ7f9@Cqaq6Ds/Heh/aleXXNtZyhFXrw5Zz9h5LyYavvEihlzQBqpLMO/eRF6URsG4Fbzg973uCs7N2G8xtAELvwsoOf27Yc92WaC3rNvGiAqlxU9utUb5uvMeCVLjD5wyNla9c4wu31LNEl5zJOzI@cSNJ9vYeHNyV4MjH5e2xPv7kOXume2iE5PaI0RIb71HihWT0SsJ5K7SAt3Y5tecCKO1WeIPx6v5cYce623Ps@ezuRTg6g4pDOxkXDmHhG0UyLHNmrhqrunxe69nqbUZ35c0PcTjzJTk4apzGB/Tu2/9MVTMZMj2ETzXDX@9omaCDswS69Dnas4sGnRyErKGLcosMHsmV2ugTY4bbUfhs8CqlfuX4Vrhl7Csm1w8nt4WVbgnL3ZLfjTD0ZFk5o94CMH9LGMvLYfATxzofOvKe7hreiv3HKwt0W0XKt1SkHOHOvrV0Wlj03etFfDy64D9WUuuJMXFz46HTMXMr67DbRyOT7CkaS78Z7m@n0F3a3jJw/CMf/H11fudTY2VGT/U3qwOI05yuDAImaAyndCTiZvDyAmkHZF7DHpjcviJ74Ez26e0WxSw88bx6L4I5fjgdry8x8Eb8JMV1dr4U8TPQmZ1zjz3Ao3ELMX2F7o/741b7r5NpWTgxiGZGH5/sBtR1eKxokRwXpfj82ZI3Hh6dHB5H/FxjNlun9EqzdTrkypBFrp@c5Jay3a6/OFuBrPXnjUDcAH4cPtfKQZzZfeX4JktA9W04GVlByFd0ezFjutRgPWdCJw1XBj6bz2gb5cqWHvJdbKvC3O4K7yXFHgZk04S8PaXdRsv67fY6qjwxPqe1BxCD2ISLJRyob3jJmOWGQQkpydqO6pwuhJ@l4h6Ph6Y9Wxk0WpeGdpEmXnmru8EuO7acc/YktCq0jj1oq4HrZ4a9jjmtOqwolbO3S2HZayLVunbhXy/xH@ua5ME6Qe0az8ANEbdxE0x/1FUeBS@faisg8fOygO6orXUv7VvL4efL@aleTw4M4icSdiqVTC5/fSh6RBktEic20SLnJh1HhriXl2zDPwIMAWJwqNg/9IyG@0x7auCpZf5NkkltE7Kp1dR8me3g534qoHAkKUf0IvNoQV4Ntnnhn@etVNQrtlFjYkVk/onq0Noxt9gLcNHWKNSJSacq25xAyGZwGpjRxyfYJaNJDNCa1HwG3mQlaheh6p@XhiJtXjw7eLZ/fLJ78vy4kWld@eepg0rYNuQWWG34KNsToe4@2kA44va76Ry/BdnRhzFw8sML6sXwYzvLVastVW1RKXEH02xe2Lai0JFyRbqC8kkiz41CsYuDF4cd1Jjax7cmUOGnu@mQOjQRBy1SntBmFZZZlfFYh4F@0/bDr3@bikLx22UV/HoZZuybXAZCHDhOz8/RM9jdV5Djo92DJ8@P9llQwAXRnJu9ybBWznOL3NzMBbRT36Q9djUW95PEoa1qtfijOCAmLsdZhYwAkDVsoHOIFmAHzQf4qbdYYpPgAwbjYaMo//kbylVcxu3iSYgbDwoVh2yB5IlQNjY22AkQCXt4dPDp/hHD8u8/JG9EEYJgJ3gC@c9@3OPfkwgsBAXfbXNHNCqThRUhaoUgOJq/sB6AOKeuO17/9Tb6fgOd0Q8/HBF@@UYQ6LsiQLfnZNzvmuG3JNli4l@b8@3yBRkRCQU26HFlAm3suR47Mz0TLQRgGfpo8m6Z2HEzE5l5lNkufpoOP4Cn08dNoOhTe8LNSvnGZWJAaXLIctJskwrLP4UiRiLGtzeA2DsGCGzMs00Y/icV9gooEWf/K9yChCTV4zeSBKAr5JJwkI9EvGEjz1OarvLu1/6JMqgycE/A/R3fPcs8gLdf8d/64P5V7n6hIKHdtKm3KEu0QGgH068BL0iIf8R95It8NrfasUAcmv4L@CozR9BMZ4R1jM5z4HcJ2PECTqLxKTQakBu0mG@tg@dnuK0EGuKsKAqSFCoRMp2VMGZ84@I1g5yFfCGnKlBI6SwASBb0B3gimwNMJivQTYQzc1x7CYLp9vY2E3EmwagVqrxllU37RVZ8GRZ0E@IK50MsXINBGkiySAFhdT8ZDD4pNYlJkXvF1Tgyrp4DoxKF4@iF77aPCJElAFkcRwaaZJ/hxxsnML76hmU7@LnDyNdVNn1AkgpjErmSouDbufjEmQD5QCddfD@J27nAjbt8BESLjR7/pCnZc0V6lG/2rMXx7OAzLn5fk5EHcFDZzPXBNNq24mcI4hhBVMRV5Nt4wZqTpt1SOG0yINMfriBmG9y/rAzW0Cyv9@5Na56J67Y4EVns/rHt4JTJI6gMS2iKllXUQnJRpVxuZZX8GvnZQHXQZNAlZAdsClhG1zBfOWNvd2//4CuHz45vWKykmPHr0YDv17dTTUlON1qhIx6t1nKTPHikHD998ChoiEWhCxFuDIzfr4l6W00WM6EIcnGy5nrVVpXweu3Wl/gzfvb@enmz2m1Fo0Q3yqFmPiBf2t0uPaIzatcz10qrsJXP31akBTwlAnqPHzC@UdRE8uKq0dquN@1Y/CYlrOgIL2LyFnYCcDW9rU0Fif1m5bBi4ceGT/Azbl60L2ZX90VxM4sG0dC@wcQ5XZiM8z0iAZH6BtkAixRkJYi6tvcdchl9YdhQ4x9D5pbUonaiIgUuZG7DeATUSfBdZeQiC7OsvkXSIajaltkRAvtc3DJpYEAxNErKbWslkoL/cQ@eccL/0vKsMpNpK1siidyOYKXZbUZOA3hJATo0SnfPpqBNPnPG3Ng7bVl4aASuIwfY78Mpn@Iw2FemI4jXp8eRQctHwLklSAyYjIdF5bIUcAnfxukshVZkIb8GWjr1Ky6PevnELCkPjVnPHABvTyTTwNE@UtUWC@2gYqXJ7qkdF6nNFq1wa1f8GI@NR9H@QcZwZ4sC6A1dNu2eMUvEz@PJSgvyR//4@Wdn8aS4ipbIKK9vpbZ33TpvWPyiejsn0Sd@7wxM367iFuXyTS4BftcBcytxwZemymV56An05cAaSu7HE/cJOEGMSPRH@pglpja3sCczek00E3aaTI9JdW6902apFClU8KAAmVHKPrn4@J3Q7TlLKDX8uCT4enYPH2/MMWuostwCN2WSZJv4Bbg9kLjQ5mRSAB0YklQIbA1JCNQMKBHvJDIncEiD4RAXHmSncEUwfRCLZtkdxAnVmtXvscgX/ZYlR7FcrvgNuswVywyo7yY7lBUAe4PPBXI9YNc3vgM4A/VXFmILRn6T48Uo3xgvyGPfag8UJxaxuBsY82EAa2EPtzt08ZfYt6GvgHxQqTw/edQuJRWRhdZ/Bq7Zw1UgbjQ@VPH8z/xAN1WWosarXKP7GJOhncU2Ny@E5v4eUYcRr7HUWBQN178fv6BNVb2V6v2EfitAzBwOAP4pyXYADm1jBtNDK8JWM/uf/Qy/UC8mNlX1tO2epeL5TBVuajXP8uyjzaYkbTYytfubOmhRk9ezJujkylbu4Zkx7PcOBkpTFFmW5RRl6@LiIv5o65n5Is8KUs/UCq9n86tsIft6dpVVS69Px2qhIb@etcRSLX3aYs@eff62/TYpzs7mr8VmQovtHV6Kag5V/lilzC52CtnYaRnUT8iXsVP2Bq7TPsN/cr/pRdw6ujt9UGHjIos1m/h5ebEoKkoj3oJ/UvdfwsUV/0Zdrss7rbdvkw1dn8zmzDTNsdfrwc8ZggSpJY8Z6Mv3gNPzBApr0pM0KLxGs/7N@YQ8Y7NdYzCY7ut1DQ/Qyvfb1bk5fTR5@vXPgus5Xm@OIsne@J@cTaUSktRYMU9Raev5GH689s9@snGVvnjW3v6zb44UYwMfh/j4ztVTdB@r@Y82Nj568CCXS2uaxt3Pvv7sF3d3d3MP0/lnjfxOTspsbP/pn2xsaNq2pmy0PE9txRunp5@LWiYnyn/2o3j72bOveV49@39@421dxVsRbmesCHwCrixTwYn3EvxUlLHe94q9iQGVq7E5/bVjgf/FBlPrO8X/8r3D17FJrK4pn7nwnMRexwqlGHeCA96ywdtZrB7bxmiFq9hcqdVq4Cz@l38L6etfATgYMt@GWz0fwCrMY3WpRkkuY/UCOFRNg3z/7298I1JCziZqJMYF133WgEvMFTVxpwXXFl3bAlpVlDKKEsSzJ8OJ4TC1dE@9hy8mvMDDNtA8vTFpxvDz3ezwPmNHjVQq1ZLbElzyC5okUlRVa6rqPWAH0kdbtZq0xbjdyGw2fw9tXydpSmvgwIhp3PvsH@KKrfKs/tzgjoRYYeP@y4f1OtQpW89u1VN0@R2J@lSxJDrOfZGl2cs4qCCN1ssnjBu7rYuZkiam0@n7bXqfIa6kWUhJePF7LBb6YJdl1/2WkkAU3zf24fFi@3j9@f/259//8@/R3/fp9x/Q7KTdM/vKFkQ6gy5Rh@t@pdKt18W6K1408b0OdJSplColpX3VTGwBB2odMTXz8WU8n40f809rq4w1k5QaLsq27meP7/XYwrvOfepRPz@ARyYP5teCHEtYI3eItRvxYGj1N@hKjbN6S0KBqCY11EK@JfFU9eAqs8Z9aCZRK5bFVl3La4fsfnvGLzbc9JgTA82wEODRL299Ubd6GLJ4q0e9YvUgWX0R50PjheUVYo2G0jJoQAj82P2NykapUqhoSru@/gLSjL5SVMMwnnmxs1h4cczGFgiNhaR53S9oivCFBRTMPiQeSEbvw3yplbIFVaz6Lq3NxCoQiZaVtEFbzKhi2Ntwfh@uDfijf7jCV7xvkI/vTVFuXhusom5pWSX/UWFfw/H1jitaVgHGCdbtdDpvuh2QOnS9o3d1daJP9Zk@1yedaWfWmXSnXYZdZnlGP@vknZIzY5wAZSmWzaubsXtE1G8bG@yIc6EWSwVXM3Xn9VyW276THA7@JMmZxYTYP8BVVzWVbcH4lIEbCGXkBJ0Z/1RVYDEQtC5ab7cab7egg9ZT28QcW3XJLyU85Pb9Vkq6umqAu1r1/7frobNKF3dB5VpXqdT2izpIHy/qjRSAfOGDlCVGQOV2vbVNIWFmfm5@8HYL5Bcptd3Yrjl79JOpg0jxnBMvOPdbAHh7qbD376dkcN0HAPVN6I/JVGpTkjZwbGz4YwVEbtVTQa2wDAmQFi4ufs4fKHrQi6@2r@pXje2rq@1t@N@m@5X/BN@r7Rv/9Fhca@IswlvIWpoNpd5Umj6zaMG7rNTRR1aa4KjDE@I1slqp1UAHXHLrv81/Ob24hz5Y5JYMpRZiW2wrhkYQs7EtIfby3Rf/C/6a7774fZQXGfwZFSF2gd1a2UJts8yVTrgx@6nNnvLLBjf@glf0QY@ndfS0@c3GBSlFeSmzCp/zT6ilQlLGAbjt9NtoV0FmLyHqDd7HRK1UENspda6x2LZYKBK7@4UbVzwe/0cvtXIxzidq0DDAS8/znkZKuSgnRK5qGVVSL@vc9j3/TMkvrLr@0S@su4TYZZkZFcBP12McM0IMCCmmKJIEI1Z9e4Rbx3GtREK19Kz2ufR8V8J5FH1CK2FdPkdQO9ivlct1vsyz@Yy6zdbDLbir8L@/AfVgzT7EbfZr3RFIwM1@Nq810VJ6TOq8xr8nb/CPnXTx7@g1/rGTN/h3NME/9rSDfyev8W@3g38nI/x78Br/nr7Bv@cD/Gt@KZtVq@LmBaEmpZbVq82ZSCiqxnbqzS9N3HnFMuyG2Wv5HwHK5sosGWt@yZjhp@Ar3LMf/@l3v/nNeK0Wl@L0aZWc6rhMTVYB@1AjL169HxdiNbapbqoZK9PNqB21Aw6TZVyWGWaGag8UlbbKMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9cBvxlwGVm@iwzYBk7Y0NECAXXpJ2ZoKsPjwH89QGQC38m7oTsqJkug4wsFNroq4wIHlyX7abQYHEmvjRA15RVOSMXzBZ@y6YhvnzZVLZaWrnEZCQqud142Yy3xKaI9s21co515sZG86UIQ3NG5MSHPizmeaDAVmNKs6lwNAEGCItXV@32/icP220Fh6HmU@dw8X94OIq@3vo/OnSeHjojB/4PDw@h6xj11P0UMOj792vAsP3HTqxe3WlWiO0HrD@mbO8061kJ3YUUcHMN/VIfeC0gwrO@0RTi5wnUPc5R/ah@dl49q5L7PHgFR7u6iBBE4w7/Cdc5DHGBOnIO19k5OugNneefNUMXdyifnYPXZwz0rvAfFLzo63@Ff/O/rf@nz1mSJRqtZOLiajtBVxL/ksmLq4sr/15PJhL@S2Ib/tAD3jHJxVUdnRTpAlyNRLKVvLrifnBPJLc5wDpks12ntIt4MCzEwiwpW35L/Nd9Qtb@1YxXQe7lunU@Q/0oJlaZvthX02zOMplktRN8ugFXifVL2ryQrNJ3@zY7DbX1pz@iz3PsJClSPletqluMv2g5rVrNBW/FUrVaCl42E4nyzaue2VELoH/kcslktQovOwHYDLxC2gZ7m2I11oR76949nklJu7wMYGZzhVRGzWDqIKc8ZGt4etdnuBcHh/RlC2A1@Rh@UoazkkSGvouD316LixXx3r2E/033nd3kvXtaOXN5GfqMx@ClLnm12z3TbbfRP3t5KbZF2gdTzsN7pnR5qWbKKTWedNzEJ/jRPsgqIansI61OuZaBjWu5IgT7Bchvbxdy9XohBz6FUjyJa@oNLH4LyhsX41UxdkF1UEtFzgHFKnpH9wdBX8ZBgV1cxahBWS6fTAAjTYIMeBXDPxd5Lh9u8vkkYOZK5DHVcplHTbJcIVFKlf2/2gZo5SDk8D@U1LKp3FZx6z7IvPjnzVZdyJOrF0ZNvapdGBWcVb@qdv3PH6N1COPevWwZUFTKVJtCu/1w92S33a6JooiCEtzQk7i7gEYz3HiDap4vtzhGKtX71MxqKc@gPXkcKQ4jBCsB0hVtK6@WEEmC2UfjL4ASgWtLG2xD0OiJN6HMMbcBnqDOQOY9uFiPddgALzZA5Y2ZzKKLWYyH073bDSM5/PJDw1dKS/pd4GOEl@D3wiwnURjEnz3Z3ds/SWvbEotpj3b30trx8wcxFV/zi3cKzuL70f7uw8PnkODZk/3d4/2PDz7df/4M/D12vrgCpu/fF8@oa8X7OftMeOW@0Q1DN6aG0T6fTs9fs1em2TahMa0pVMoZuMwz2lCXsb6oVxV@XdPTX73S3TFd7N0Pv/3uh//du9/57rvf@fa73/n@T7/4/rfh92P4fZc/v/tvynm8//SLf/a77377d8DzP8Dvj@D3k59@8Rvf4D96/2P4/aeI3x/7v0g8/hMA1q/89Ivv/einX/zqD@D3L/3fD27@fu0nq3/f/9b6H6b73u/eHue7/xZ@v8dhBXG/@9vcD5834v82j/erP3j3L/4d//9T/w@dv/PuX/wx3vyXf/qDP/1P77757zWt9Kf/@t23vvfuW998963vvPvWP9be/ca/VjPR2@@@@/4f/NUf/t5f/eH/SP8/pvvvvc//ux/807/4X//if/@LP/R/P4HfvwPXT/7i30NX@ds/@CH@f@8P/vaPfoj///O/@ts/@PW//ZX/iRy/yR3/z7/8N/z@17/2H//mt77zVz/5xt/8@k/@5jf/4K/@j1/9v37jP/71f//7f/1Pvomev/mTv/qjX/nLb377L7/1z//ym1@suX/71vsX7@H/xT@Az/uX833gvE@9PtTni5@rPH8fbCxyAToB6v7ld7/xS0Dg/4Kxd9/@MZ6rgt@a/x9rKsX5MX/7/4BDu1lnDMmAC36//u7b30UU/Q@AIvgP8fWd8GUphL98Z/ECaP2tFYl@@adf/PMf0VvMqNRp1QbH7pJWSm2BfrNVLvvjt7@gA0l@aRlaCMDP6TvIoZbCvoO87d0Pv/HuR//43Q9/890PfwUHbylXTu@mJfWO1TCImH@PeBix8D7xMOLnmH@Kptik1Ofwxj73Az///HOhfangAb77l@D7OXnxi/EgPODnBwVh6I8n/tgli7p9Z8Z3bvq@Yc6MNV6@bOF6K/hh7imSPbYC0SifZbOUX7AZ48s66A@RZlvknOGdfDF4JuBt8b9wzgSWmvnTvfBMLZzk8NP5WXCnkIdsUrNwMYlkNcaloy3uQ@vElG@uzLAGs1lqBkowOCCHFAQ9AHG8VkthwhovD7zyotVLjIqSStWg3piap0m3Swhi9oCgQMpa6oi1t2oznjCF8OoBOlICeh2JqiamSrWHkGFt9pAhLAROYF@@rNVLtVkdwb3l@EjNUg@oTAislprV38J7jWBCOiH28C0UpVRLpeolzBAryZsn3eaNlKfKUd1TLOW3ATxxu//OfcY@EtWSyBcJNhBhPDbeU4vYGBGiQ3gzteVXh/4DJ/22COEblJWfC@PhOySb7nBxFSMAXEmSZZnBD9ffd9h9CJ5xUCnKFh4pDiFFFEEUEHownB9KCSlq3xS9QP6x2tYHXwgMK7O5uSnE6mJWPJQJdYrC3NMKnX3A7YCoXlSYWCiL6G3QQZCgLJC@SvlvxnFhLc44YPZRiv/u399iH0E16bnwE5iUyjo5J8ahbKdSogbw605KeAFqiQB0SoAuBXlWo4W8lJBOMybXYhjGDg8P/UKQx4uakAIy17IqvuNy0nQ6jUEKWU7L6bT/lOlJHrLvkCnUf8qbiFz6qjXTtFwVtKcqQy8WVXVUUIHR8@3bt9AqtL@qcgDKJ/O3Wmm5EgWCB7djYlnz4MCQlisLXDNnaiHHWIKmWOFKsqTAEmwrKfBd@bwQwZWIa6VSnOIB9uXEVrDzrqASOeD0aqyOBQ0urhKW8skgcO@Q7R0@fbr/ycm41WKCQV/pNtpj1@kanpfAsN1PHvITGVq5kIw1Ggj6pKIhgxH2KxlixgcPjw6OK4xX2m@CBBWsSuuqfjXLqhAbjz/bjvk7j0T80JwjHuO9sqhbQitnIWmsLsS6BmoWuGCOCnCVVYWn3uCBMwOdPi2KabWAml2SJpWZ8IvOlKEZVG4zBfoUntOQt7cJA0L9QqKlC3RCaxWEet3fs8dUoX68fwIJTg6ZqmVkof45m8mYoXQl1K2aZdiDyXATN7@JzYwYqdNmI5PGPy2bhbuaK6TVfLG1sWFdSJhnk5rtAncxXsHrhYTV@DJcTPiywL4MXnBBHrg1kfn7Qg8Oq/7mPDQ4luA79EQ1D90sKeA8NgcnjKNXFah7eSFIiG18/esTVq@Dfi0dPBJiwC2GLNifJpk9eShTM/emrkGhA8Z65qcmfkFQ7pne2NLn0HUAG7Grq6s@QDp4xLS6Rq88RQ/vV13y6YD7aqYLMbtSqb1Vc0VBO61U3mY1TQAPYUvBDXAbQAC0j2BL4X9VDzLJZksKcCpVFOGRzWYFnDsWhIohMNor8jZTq0mcBrM5lbaKCPhRCn1W08LLjzv7aBE3m@FxMQQC2GDiskwQVuRh/ltBoDdAGu6Oo08gV/3Ombl3L4uTGNlcJpytoBqzK2ibzWwuixgX/v8LD2Dx1ZztcT2bUbeVMTh1cOa2FR2cHXDmt5UOOE1wlrcVE5zTelbNbCvTusCEbW5ylKFFk5o4MWZo4Zj7iXXPsPoyni2qiZSBJm77JrzrQcJ6r9ZzuvT98mpPNvE78nj@mCfI5cSqY6MxvBqaxaAT2yyRvBAGtXM6JS0YtYGM9lVcW7eEntxxenPZm8wtPKVjOW4tDuJgPAhYQDdADsG5r51sNldpsJY8dsY7gpYvphpqBgYQ/KmltJbeMHaKxUpP7lqG7u7kK/lSuocHgPwlrp18pjKQP3/65PFkMj4y6FTQTq4MCdAiGdoO2ilV8vlWoyGKqQZl08KvL3P2JG1sQJ829J4ET1wA8ySt1ILEPdOt1eLxnayqSWolmyldCQvEIc6xhnUBk6awZmnE@4XPASq2YwOzqaT1tHlBWKj0@/2rrYvU4kXQLyT@Bvi5kvR05yJ8rUqReBU2TUvmIhB89D6g@8Jf26uIWr4kVhvVxXuxIFZbV8L9kdEzdTwM1Mxc3ExVAKbMocYgoyYTriqu40wqHaPvuMYiYlYtBBF5gW5GyIlXYXbNDOZ4cTO7QiTS7OImlFxevApTBcUSrq4A7xzZgHbfnmydNs021HKutQ8sCMhnOzA1i9FiL14Isa2jT7P1OjT1Ra6o5fK5vJYtFPJFDcabcq6QL0FnyxQyeU0DKLlyqVy8ArpWlLcx@pIc27sI6L1CtvQTeoUbg2y0WPLtJ6Z1UcpKvByJZPXqKvZWiH109KkGA@TaKwGD7qeaVK9l82VwZdGlZaHATNA0SctKWVVSs/h/h0PD//ePr8G/hndIldWEE7QQ8wkMmzDU2@wJWpqYOOzEwW8NDdgDo7smxt5Qpx3Ne67jeX@POA90@5QHPTS5WdYw6LGOH1zzRuZkuCbG8/EIjcsY7j8YhP1RBwqI7JBHeAA313KcVRGK7PmzNbV8GhpCB2RwS@gQ/ejg48cnkefJ/u7eY6HAHhx@8vDaI@9HyrMn@49OwtciDw2S5kMQv7j/5Mn1V/@RO3x@1J86Lv6ER4fPc4tb6IUHZoUcXMuRQm8C4t/wlQRLkChAEcsXA4cq4DGLe6Ac3/Od@cLCmUHnZ/w0sOmF2/75wfCKcBIcEdYZctqOwbrchhBq62Tfz5fl1WJZEMbMds5ZMcN6jmXp@PX4/gZ4DnU87migQGtZSImY9bnjWr1zs2dsCE/xZGVZxS91YyGExwBkNO2SbQgQZtBabA@/647LUh1rarDpmK31hAd6odM1B0MYg8@dIILQ0XUGvw@9IL0RvSa3e0x4HuR3I8S6GV0Ana4kinui@Fif6PWqa1S9TKVy7576zBXLWXEMY7LuDYz9GZAtew7dSHfn6ZI4kcVHrD3AlQ3LGaMO4o0bILSXtUZrJ6fVS5l8tvTXv/Xjv/uTXx/U1K1mZi@zvfP0Sb4CzA3kWEaiqi/OyqTYaOVSvlTOaqV0qVzK5dVCPp9WtTTohMUyqAUZtaQWSvmymi7lyiCH5MoQmi8XfWFYCaRfZasCYO0ufjt6m3QjeQhKEF@IZG8SepLF9PB9ykQD0ogCqqETOjy@ZdZgCGVqhmWLDCDqrMtijx7tZR49EsUH@IIbOfYyotjDl3wpkyk@EEWDQvZKKFOJDk9TQit84oS/ZDIPAMtTDgAN2IviEF/2CzihJoomvuztPnqE@fTxRcP0EO2Uh/AXK3gpQjQbX0BGJwCvQ2gQbZfnk6OC7uMLZokhj3jIHoSJ4sdBcTDkiEfjAB4HNd3dFcUD/rK7iyF7VO08L@hX8WWXLlF04QWIXxQH4Bi40O1EsQNO7AKi2AVXd66DH36nG22c2xNdFOccPYggUZxRbL17KortwB@z@dQvTR6xW6EXldf6Pr2U8U8UtaDQGC0bvmRFMRe@5KBujx9/qg8nPWPAr7nLn12o6ePHWd2cTfcfdT7@uDMYdNz57v7HRxi0t/cY5JH51O0MOn7CThsuB1LtPdb009H8@gW1Pmi3K7q1Muir7XZOt68FtedtA0sIqV5DyfxrgBmN2nsQtPe4fV9ftZBMANvY@0fw7OD1YATPB3qHBwUXBdFz1umIVSR/RWkmBNQYcAkYu@MpcFM7PdK7rlPF91mNZdIotMwbhUyrSgFsBJJ/pnqF4f0E3nWc/UlezBuzWqZVm9WKGt@J1E@IzZmWN8X0xmhHLecrG/qOquVSswrar3D6cRaX1B2WUO9tvWGJT5I7GmgBYnNnRxIbamtHU0uVQvHF1lQUkxW872SLlTeJTDzDGN6SjWJrp5iPpCgWU7qiVYpFkMUAJxMY0js4KdNOJM4N/TSZxNLSFAFUgerK5lRPs9pPzNKzGi8Xmyers5pa5bZ9WeYGsB4akp92J47LQQ4A3GwnU8E1@ISolksiFEBREslkyPRAYxcWm0A/@9rJ6cnJ5yT01f3Zi2cuffm@6r9@/HhPPjgM3tAEvPwIZVHHlfeQay2FcKE08DoBLUR@DMMoaHSBH54TdB1L3qe9cyDQBgGBUSPZN8cqnzxegnM8dM55zmhmoUo2/eyuwdBCvtljeq0OLr3HElQqpifPaQBv1@u1dm1ElgigikGqrzIyH78Ac@DxsofGHyj5BZ6d8wPatcxVtVObxWYAp11jkvpy5PReaqlutYeG8R/UHmDiahuenapRM1zXcUXQp8Vqf8euTW1P7xvPDBfNmhwcboI4gQfqEn1mJDdZcx9j76GuciXVXWYvSvbJdJTQpXonueyFM3OhByIn8bWg0hd0xhN3aVxV@zWWeAFRX8O7u8kSPflBcidXBTw9YO0keGVe9l/2mcYKuSrpGgmEBV2J8IP11lmyVv8qPDjs00oFSuM39ClAxcwAsNmjAIg9Nq@q3ZrFEhKbsSQhKVcd1BqY/BJv25IotiSpcdkS6pL0mVCH/lqdx/SaN@3QN1VYpqNqmUJ1Bn5qMVcdQvPqL2ZVtzaegohgwas/ocePs@pVQCrgDsC8uUy8@6VvJLelfI37VQnUpQWiR1tu12ZVG600AmHUsjUISDVymTRo8XArpmHM1wpptZDOpnNpqYi@MOCn82nwBC0HBIyElRAZE9OZWUZW06qhphOZl2bvZTJ9mgDBhZDGkumJs29PRwx8oKmQNukVnoCelLZlgfbVc5i@LRGxAsuoYsUA60M2NtNDBHVk6BalSCYllt1KWJsJjLN5Mh3vN1qVyv5s/DUISkivdwqpYib1JpmsJjaSNc94LdSrQh3ZC9V6vAGU6891Mm86akArg0stapVGo4NVLGbS2UwWame2LwfbYl1spTMbBRWa6IoR22Ccb0Sn/1DiWfiN2yh9WwY0nVrWqoJMc3HZkiaVlfxWPsPnA3lKYeyzN8QkSzTF4Oh2Ih4vavF4Ml7FlYgN0Z96Bp5G/CwO3DV@T90RQRgTK2JZwwgL1kinczNB6UAcuxJQKmQ5UG4vhKuLq@268CXhGM9cbmsv8K/44unuIf59CbzK8Fp68fT54fPDRwJTaLOn3I5VN6pytV2FF0mu3xdiFcaAkzZ9u1LKBmMfuo00tV1/wZ9NPD8AcAWyvNxgLdreZZioubFP0WbBDotDHXR31NC0bKuhFWHsA24aRNU0tYrrNDE8oSDXoTG8CyjfdqqOx/2@yuZzPSUF6v49xgapTYHQE7s@F7Bb2x0c7QY71Hb3Vs8YbM4UnKRuCqKIO9piF/FY/Ar@YnF@uKqUF98E53YKYvU0U94WYvfpXKLGzyWyWHgyEZdd/RWTbK7AkuVgQeNL8fuxeDyOKwcV5r2NUZMGJ72@@lIDaorZTuABChVOdsFol8/j9HpMeTn2vq6Vsk8PDu2H7iOD@WXLtcV6DL9GLeEBqmrlRXvjVAUqyorZ03SM3Y/RpnuxXNJEjXtUY@yUqUGFID14tONqJZ2@D4VtblxuOLiEwsKNfW/tr3yNsXE8m4sz1qzFZrWcv2NcrdcldVtDi25FVoFhoq8WpMxlnXeEOgUUNAh590s/yM22S/CuZVR417R8SqvX1S2NJWPjd1/8Phrnudj/dPcJi@PE@9/9yY@04t/9yb@ivWnxK5qM17LFGMREp1ooxi4uxhcXV3DxsHysFeOFyhWT4OYLQ2qsrqha1rbtKqsour5VTOW0@3ZV8eOqRTUZ86SYvx0zW8hLiYSqQKm2sqVMEsIu/ZhapgRvwZIUjy4WoG2gAvtHZl5T72/vQP12sjmtugGkoYZHVln4t214ZVQNn768ZAxeuvXeYGBq5FIUVnkrse230jZ7iwtCb6UN9rJWx40FKh50DRZMtvDgHy4axuspZSvOQK1i9cZV9aqVohUXUEBfGMaW3bxG5s0NPPmx7LVlw5@x5dEfJgo8PHgN3oytV56Y2EoqSq8n3uw@2wbL14FgtpTFcVy2Fayj8D9Jaibf/dJvaFrh7/7k1y7bl@3PNVBNy@WCqsV@9rPtqT31jF79ZwDgFsMsgXpJEiZaUEFHqJYybu/R9FOFDrkLGvHURhGcxw@UVFRLGYgv5sA2eqSkCmcoclHjtrltwF6Com2h3YY0ifBkiytZFYRA1uUiujvopgkG20IjpY1WUrgQvoxBMKIzEPOrwpcXoMBjBGO402171tQd08mZBKVTW2l2D5JADl9Gs4sbZG/CHw4k4IvK1s2kvMgeYY3EMzYyPA@NOMJIJnwZkviWnK05G@toGgVjmjaMPzJGoXJSQK8Bebcgb4snaJNvgmrPI6QZLx1PZIMYL3wZJBLCggmCCjO3IUIVWNaXAQFQh4QP2GyxbZZNsgszlaouLERe4R5/tGGpB2YZBEyG0HpoBiRIXMV44AXqA347FOnCb2GQEyOeARAOg28JqIECgsnpDWU/spvy3qAAFtkoS1DV2L17i1LVamYvyahGCP/UHOMEGrWDvbqsACxQ3j7qVcQ0Q9ub1cA3JDvAeIqKC1QncaOb1UhSJuLrlSDA/3sTLVLktaaigCpWwG8v3iu6gDJIjGjnbdhl2zWmasUkCwvfhbJ3qVB0OD7USJuzj2Tt8yDwCkr4s1jwZR5gWifRSUmfbq/b5WAgr0/xsyhonY0zA9@eBre/hszvYBKkDlNBVUyLYvdNF3Ql2qsQmH5MZNUkJluYyqRyEB/Xcgw3w@eT@KBUGJvBU0cThn4@G2R6qetAg3pjxyabh2STCU8iAEUAj/LNxfFiT@1z/IyW3zaUOFoij0zFIeVjicmGI31/nNLiZoGOCzp1gJs0MwYy6456TCuzBBEambWzQ3BJSkQF7oDIjTjuWMYIinRsGHR8zasoygDEsGmHbPs9NYGuho9MGIFsT/E/9a6cm6emcoL2bCWnj6fcuKWUGEpu2P34vgTfjp7lOKfMMk8NPtecWLIz4zFQOkBuTgNmFz9AbAU3vGjZNM59qGkeC35FeBS5s5SOpN1IzJM3n1l1I9HGFr2k8cZ08TPuZ7odwS9dl4KvbXtzL7BURfaW4F0OWa7h26ipxdH6RGh8SfBtbtXI3JOMaxjjhBgTA1tV6BTGrnHGUG8WcIwBptkNrL5gL4bafpkGAOp70LPQhOXEraCtIiiJ20t0oev5DN5mH7GsJmBEbkjMN/oFMLDpa8vQIQySYj28SQ8aRqaJe@Qr0DtHPQhDKxk@@WH6gLrRTeZFF@TNNnxwOOhQXjXGu0Xwko@8YO9Aeqaqb0BgAUq4oiQbCTEFYFNiUuSgw/TXk3NqF4iXVNhNSGmGEHxUAxQSFXRkOWijMPK9KwECHuge/yiCb@Dy/PxcJqurU9eUDQ@/AeU5tm4p44EJ0rajTIzR2P/arolfWffhLlwS//SbPB6Od2Yo3dbK9@b8KQh9r@ZvG0rE@14cB8cz/MTRYEQW2tA0mkcE9cikz6N1E/4uJk5/Wit9EdBfBelPKsWvEAhjCGaWnqe7aQCW7nRP0/3zXtUPOKMOCcChFY3AE20hu8HLyAtc5rgfxnAmyEfDoI51SivBAEnkk8SLrHkNg5jz4NV/H5szSGQb52zXdfV5gsKTGBsJODEnsYfNYdinEHDCMMMuuGFec9aYt5aSz8LkMKiF@yBcNL8mXNwOlFtpxvAZD59B@IyHzxaZBtk2Zi0ukqHXFVYHqR6tdgYxEcw8iHPFLRovQggyyOOgRZEfxpwv@V3Br1uj1AG@@Ru0Yy0gDKCJMSDcSCiNF81Gs2V7xvlWK6UMgNhFQgS0OIButAin573Qjdi3zqyx4y152WisFUYlv9zo1R361MBpBesYNhARBseXifY1ByN/wwYXCPwKAwSUwyAQRYPdScJMVkOr4BQIhNMQFzjmBWv4hWmR9OUH@X4gLnHUc8RGAbUigNA/rBIUE0JY0HP4F/8C7vCZ60CcIK5EHykboZ23eCsOmLzWVTivqVIjRUolSUExAe0ortauVyUIh6ZoXAuKVPPKb/9o8Tc@uPh96BerS08EyweMqhDtKrhHEkQIv7sQVlm9FmlXKIGypVuGCyPXPpdP/dEastlSAjWD54NV8M7NSXeYiDR@N8nbh05iirZYCUlhXqtBFec13i15vwhQyhEeJvP8ZPOAEPz0nIEAjMzKZIafbBZNNqvVOONgszXJziOFnFEhZzwJjz1bU8iWnwy0p4NgeMHmaYF0ips4RYCn8mEUxKCxyDz9zMBl9VdogxIXJvw8FzyHqMCnIRSxkc66rZW5NyKFjjCtawCQEG8A6PGPB1eE6wxPlcK3kEdxVAY8ir/5ZMB5BRAYseAqt9OcCImMdGAQ@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmlzGvwz/ienAM/ipNz0zyzHVZc9M@trfP4hnCzEb6aAR6UPN5JAhoybz3PYNnEZljhjbnYKCA1Jd59xhiRXCNvgrUz@p0rGcjjLScXsMflKU@8rjeTLQH3B5ht0fOxN94uRyFa40mUR2q/LnOoM5sB38ElHEVjvIej3H8Oz4BBq16wxs0zPSDM1onhq@2mH4H48QonKy73Q8QfA3anE1FkFzukJRt93Gj5y32wnc/5ishJu5aTskkmc8LqD@C65IemBPPtDDccLpvDK6k@TdMPHDA36yE7N7mjgc@4E4pbrLgId1Qf6H0CFIMMxzFpojGTVHUbozSdAHM4bOyBmA1Df1ZAFTXwN/sICNBdLHYypLmumo0lYin5@gXpLopvWkn/SrH5yUfVVL6MkwvbYMYAkZaeZexzFi1l2RXXttdjxZkN/xh5f3OFre49vLS1r49TJz1bzGAz8s62xiAQEiLoqRvbsYWHXgW70bxVkqSuiNchVP8N5F7NH2sx6WdBei7vrR5T7QRzp88@AtLPin6/B/ewMGyffft/l06PbseA78ZoQ7ORP08TgvWGVNQPSDJPKem9mFpP3wPfOCuPjdzkcoQoAYS4zLRnvM0DHHoHZ74QRyAPgOmscdXzfonraB1XjgijK5Z2l2qq1vooftnmHpc6OX8GOmI3CDGh@Bwkb86v0qjoyOmJ7Ddb0EjF3JMBSGcUQ6j1RZQzJ6@iyZXE9WPIoZUg/NlFMJD9bjD8NvsGac4qvx2WrQA@LxGE7Hnpk4/Tmej@fc5L/Fvxzm81E@/vCWRGsSdyME8MBHTzW9yDZ5G/s8SoRVeo8RIYwrL1cZLXIHENFI0802/DAU3V1TaNxIolrQysLyx25Wt7h5W4tHqCKgSb4Y9X4keRfRvTfNRUiNA1uwsL0PG0JuQMatId1uIgqR@9zaYo59gyegH83T2WtGlfYKhhqmJE43MUndJvkiKaBmfABPnHD6FJ4IcGBM2pyggrrhnJb/MU5GISN9HJFafB8Q0gFKBIsc5X4xIrGEwA3RL67CPLtr8@zeyLO7lGfYA5azjEQSuktZ@q2AzXNbE1hGf7KGO2MQ6s7wuI1tw2U7uouzFRdxM14x0yx@Fq8AQ47/v91921obyZLuNXqKtIQblSmVJGwwFghbgLC1FgYPB7u9gVYXUgnU1qlV4qC23d/MXOwX2HM/j7BfZd5hrvZTrB1/RGZVliQw7l57r/lmfatNqSozMjIyMjIyMw7BQqmaJaG80FwobfNDuFA65IdPC6W/0kM8txa@LJTMtECBIf3kh1d4r0U4fjcWSltZ52tq5H8KQtOut1CKxpTKvJSfTBEiBfpNWiOu2Hp93c3RMKCFjZVKV4FjQhfbJz6Hcfm/Av1f0ldxYht8xBnnEy6sFlUxsWhYK4a0Q8uGSZwwYyaX9Gpe3d9h06qoCJpZpD2eXYfBkxqeWUgKI0EMX/lGg/4SgpCbpdkYKWsleyA6unXiUB7kZPtMPY/1gWaWv59Q4bO4Ec5Zpuub8UqCkAF8GJ6ofBeeU@iY5hgj3Mk6M9ACUX9euKdTGOskLnr07RHis@5kIcI2Z4rIKDFYS6aTDseXc2hs0B8kmYS/woi/bdfhQzmZlODeiWosFfTMvOMzv9Y9g2CwJ79zX3esekAtIYLw8aRwJrMsWhdYFuNTLOssTVUmH6FgyRya4UHjE@eD29aPXE7EjctrxV3LkKkrTbLkSopJquwhOtaVP5LWo81rFTGzvm/7amre4qwlCwBWzagVka/979Df@6K/G4XaEGGigVmK9eyldFq9vneVncC8Ezc7PYD46KptZ6ZyFLUQk5x2B5Zmfh@vTan4MPkQJV8ajaBPaPuGbNGe4Bt0m9xbCCxoCcPr5MtPS/Ty09LdhJrWSDrXnlFaPLSk4UjHI0zjrt2Pq3R81hDjC59v@53vHuBhcoDtwQM87sBwguQyy4dXPbZyiec2iW15A5FaLCkR5HxdGg1z/JLEPV/dRte29GK/frC9v7f7kRbd58@fO3qNHsf4YdbirDVaxwUy22lH68GMbcuSi6RNuOzGcXx42R@OHp320lOyRIQ1KQM@tWLYT89xR8syS55PzF2qJ2UtimpYn@Jp4CekElQdH0t2W9N1RAQJRtknvgZi1Fuit8u7NYfTE9XrPb8b1Ou8fJlEwnoVw9CYG3Hnb5lH@atwyAlzJbfWTSrFYSrU9r768KZypI7eVNXO8dZf1cf9Y/WhsneECAXvjjd3a1uK/qvuHVZVKmGPiTyE2FASXbeDRoDksmqpUHimGPJWfzAWuZPdcuT9od9Vb/qNANdU66HffXUpP7xeMNqQWlXajo5xhtnmvJPd9gj2FpwokbaxUG6a7HgIxwJFZc9pT9vFnrfbb7ZbbSqbwt530A5C46umOm0aQZK3xl3bFSUJORHZdIhzncIC64aq@1QedzcExhf7K5AYJSSJYtNTmnDR/76bgkfVg7eHCsEutvb3tmtHtf29Q7Wzf0A/332s7b0metYOjw5qm8f4xAXf7m/XdmpbFX4hCBQ8hSgUv1yFo3tR8FCcqdL4hJtvb0DDH/1KnnpDg1c3Prtghmrhqgfp0/Y77d@C5sJa6iqE@gK3T74qUNn5ysHr97Tmq@BX3HCaq2C2P0gfh5ync76g1rk1miwbNN/W9HSlZS9XdPg@ojtWSNUTrHF0iiw/u8oAZyOeZjtQ6S3YqODsW4JY8Fw2oKmhRwQboIzBSllxiq2FBXedQW5Qa41OHxFHpTUxItQ/UPWVMTVZSzHFtK0MgMJ1otbDeVBxLXpBfE8vlnSzo6EUUE@jF1JAPZMXUEVrsB1Ry7rE1Wj/CuJZrciLX7qDHb4WVs@jF5s@72JXNU4ybjykvopSFCKkR4cTqckpDyd75SzjXCXk8kgy1unIxAgkvSXJRLlKZNs2KpkmYdPCVYM2e5Os0fhK3AA7Ib81ClW27HjqCMZBQa8tKewuOn5PTKBi0x3mPbWK6Ell7eHdjlK/sTPKoM8MiLSTSTyiettaKwweWo9qbk616GsbSU6/akzQvoXA5hQCfwQMAcoldjoNXqnYKxZg@i3NytmwTxyJc9vf7fLEzs2rRpCooK22sr@0f/vN0UR2E/skY6fI2NEQ/RYMSa3kq8xWf0hznMUqJ8uCFGxc9gejtoxhNtkDvnHiZY5KY2Gj1n4ubyRaAx0mW@z1e1aj58TFd7R6Tkz5kFaZ4@XuPBJfcRZl4nxahMXuDuj45/3rwLo7c3GJdBPg@IUUYb4rx@HneMSYiP6ZimXH7wrJV1fLG9ubp7nff3aRgVXEgiRANkaH@I8YE23R9OB7PjZYHELv0jPNZM4Lr85RW9vgaWmJWW6A0T7wsk37ulf1teibmBtPv4ejzuR7fvnlS1lq5SCZdNbs8DIbSzdXnZgmXa5zprQJiCU7CVmS9VnzxmWYkbx@BeccjALCAfUgR7Bvn8hLp0WI6d35VYski04PrIc7gu@oDbaoiHOrw@nGHo/8T9nN8uKGk48NSpRFzqwR0a6BXHQcyyyF16spcNv3gyP5/XBwq/diJ8vDd0Hbvhfad@GWW7wblixLFqyHg/39HrCyuP0hsNR3927AskhOQ4s4PWJOdz4TWdPe3@LPU2PHc4/AYO3FCUoE1GrtqsdX1CZ@d1YqODaYWCE6PNquHhyotOxPqC7JPWwZmloMAvYj9S62tm33WNh5kdIUbZYj5cm8SVi0RW5Q90zmmcS7Q1RoHcTV9IiERRwlvNW@FamnVxZWIdj6ngWioVwSu89GBoUnGvBX2gMSsvGgWR1MzexmRhafdmgbgWu6uaIb2zb8bGEtazeS7g7HNiDbJsi/gGfJ7PH7IPpxybQjChZiKKHDTdKkab2hfcIhNTyggp6XHMF7hsUMKYzsRcHOGNrB8KuQ1LD/PEMxI4kSLrqwJda1cqxRE/143qg5bJCIZcCHpaf@KBbN9MGIeH6zbg@oEy962eQSREom0rC@srmCqp991UsYUyNaJ8uRQm7PtXnG5sRgeYbTWQ177e5Cj2ELvTIpHiabIml7b1O5v09TskokWjI0n9kZ85EgrywvP/0W7MlemOq5Pwtb1pBJ@TnqDmh/H4MMxyEf7xPn1vZc8z1mgHtIJ6b1ZsJMVCRVZ8aakug7L0Y2foSLnAsRMgh6j8y2k6066nYCt9nQZUWyoXORqT5YUzjqqMyaKep/vb85CORvtvfo@9uTyYZCMB38Cqv8t/1hGMReeVa0GOsVvOyT74LhsMfFxJ@pCyhZdmO619mOve3E4FV6hY9832b3pKW9k8Ts1jVnDdwIHy96SGaN0721yeO9XHHN7upObbeqnnAQzFbiLDI9TDuW7HnU7t2HAMtgPpfA8sE@fI/DEv1HOLgGJJGJvfmyTBvnm7gxRUhrPuGsSNosVMvW4uTot8KG30N8ETf9OFRp9weqyKew1f0dZ9bJemEtUZ@QCwe9LNVy0zkvzVXpHQ50ASkJQkYT760FC54axlIS7jUXfdhH4WIruJXTM7ac9PPF1cLKixT3rueO3O7JizP3SaOcVrT4@r1ueDW8aX666F9et1RHDX45v22Mf/tVqeVn6im1tfSDRCIurpTzHPz1Of27ql4UmHM1gi85qjKSK3uSdVapBRXvw9ceKYcfeNNcgofEBJeqJ13DhXCxG5W7Jytn5V65sNY96Z2twclvtFgeLRYXs3jxA62iJGPkZv5kdIY11T51DXrXCvE@Obupdg1R7BpCb976w3Z/t7L3OnEaBwUAR2Da1psP1CWR9Rys2eB74vWCm6w@JnMVODYFBSk1x15BRTjR83kyjmOabcKMRsUlbTa85X/HTmqu4F0NRn3@YqI7grXUl/aX1JxxYyrwiQIVOWmbGJDwLyA4cZksLobk7VisqHNFUdeK8J10LBAnqMniMH2aTsOnEIhqX66Ts1ToBX7jEkggc/sXrqbW1zmPO7Fa6PEpHkw5/CE7TBTO8IgLEPoz4NsGNMGae8huHynqPn4X8SBv@IxqxH4ybCCfYk0RX2D@rT6zfxPXXycCCOHnROfy9BGn1rxIkRTfQT5cQOi05MYf1wxwq5RBmUNnAVvaK8fA2VKcaYRmNZno/dwNyCm0ov/pHuSK/GuqG1F5R4ozSfieWv8KQUseUv60gT@duFrWqpYz1UxhixRz36QGTrpoe/Q2oGk1VltBp0NICy3mYnLgkf17dfuLUfvhCdo8i5CX77mp77nEd0@@C1JxKY8W@LhQyS6UznyOy31V6biYO9VWWbHy4tFINzxSSeKya/eVDb1Rv96OC29EQylcGX1YT3zIWV9@mjH68uVRok7E4NH3E/mu@XtJj3yEZaLsq2T7@JvSAxSw8ay2NZngUq/X7rxM6aTf@gvYLE3UVEqqczJHZSZVWftganFCGhzO@XnabpRjKItFI3F4zqQ31l@lPa1kvMxOoiFejFMTa8YcsajEbS4y4W7ZYZHa4c@PLBAME4ymzMzdMJXHuvLYAotSj0yz4gU5NcGpa5NTvAy/yC/4x0z2JHKmXGb2xznB/FY6L97NSQKx0H2Unk2mpDSBu4i81J26ZxWJ2x5PQpwtJPasU@CozUB8sFs4Bn8UyQlbUBhJMUX36IumdFygaNj3riHEx6@pv@WfpF77pGMPOsGtqmCb4bMXVirh4D4KwlGICFMc/Ca8Ggw6uHVkhe@GXah1cP2lZVy3xBCtld1L1WDZI@VdPGmHdKrkqX1AvoGBSPwhvLq4gDMZPGD7NxCtOHFpj7xUpTeWAw2aM0@XxM08UAi@wQK4076wkZCRk9kDSocDvxF4KdLRQtJ@UtLVVlunQOXzdPiNIJAZLWmlVOqfrtqNT1uvcZ/7vFh4WrRIdq2vgwve02exgxURyXxYQizC5eKzVMq6G27I3XAOAF21i4X@PfFmcB30ekGqQisGFwxJaQ2D4XXQ9FKpgyC6BAZcsDJuJuGH3b8aNuRwh5Qun5gRXsKhK9dhxGH4i/VZrosbfFfmpnBpFd8201Bft5sgoPE4afVxO8wXFggTIPRApW4wIqI8cVQSJb571riw7tLFQRRRA3FOrLuJiAy9/qjdoJHhk6xUh0DJNUjcWK85gQm11@j4cA72ZiEA95iYAgYBc5V0Hw4pfWn@XTgo3TFzx@6bkcmT9OvzXKHpHgzbJH1jAvOocDULdxrgoze1Q3W4v3P0oXJQVfT87mD/fW27uq02P/IdNy7KOa6verO/S9Iluk2XW/N9epGuHFLNNH9IVfY@quqP7w6qh4dq/0DV3r7brRE0An9Q2TuqVQ9dVdvb2j3e5tt3gqD29o/Ubu1t7YiKHe273Kqplorrqf0d9bZ6sPWGflY2a7u1o4/c4k7taA@N4Va/ot5VDo5qW8e7lQP17vjg3f5hVaFjqe3a4dZupfa2uu1R@9Smqr6v7h2pwzeV3d2Jju5/2KseKDYSsHq5WSUsK5u0hUVL3M/t2kF16wgdip@2iHiE4K6rDt9Vt2p4qP5Ype5UDj66Guhh9Z@OqRB9VNuVt5XX1LlU9htUoXHZOj6oIoISKHF4vHl4VDs6Pqqq1/v720zrw@rB@9pW9XBNpXb3D5lgx4dVVyFBIzdNMIha9J2eN48Pa0y32t4RrRnH72Dv4NAgfyDCEJYVqrrNBIYZBHpLRNo/@AiooAMPgKs@vKnS@wPQlKlVARVgUbF1ZBejBomIR3Y31V719W7tdXVvq4rP@wDzoXZYdWjAaocoUINBxkdiHWr0mHuNcSK85JGYNWU41@XhVLUdVdl@XwPmujRxwGFNcwuTbeuNprmHqL/WIUq7jzMDv2sfrLSmX10HiHM5fSIz@4wmipi0tb9dpRVZB7tKxx@OadVZnQilZH@jlSb6SD8TIWuawfnVRb3da/XhYxpVk4OPbnjhIu2Qg5wtp6l7sm/p8xWukMnU6@8rddroHtbrjvuQmgk0vlVDH4PfV8rRfUROB@y8cfBTKgnd1xOE2vhBX3SyoR4uIFBSqP@DmL753cBR@Xwz0NXgvA/A5ugolGuTS1ylkGhkZ0ckm4mb5JMJ/t3W7MAVswa816jjnBSWkVyoH9I/vS/xD1kcrBckneW4K5/HJpbRaP8WmGakEQ6JwP/oiATtFjfphUHw6SJbsJvDnt@76PebWccxdbjsiPaBF1nnG9XPg4uJ6rnJ@owsXzvrdAih2XezChPdP2uSKT0u3pB7lsU/9RH/cQw2EvMBp6bcFB9W60PL7A9SHRZJrtKhLeBewYMMne9t5cfaB@zmCkvP1ibev4ney9yCvSAi4tKCd8L1zvjPmzMpQBOMY3EQSdo6QkY@b9Ux9iZR4RsqeIlCN@0mLH9orb4MeF0nkpAie@V37DaxGg/btzb2JIdfH1Tebh7v7JDoBLbPVpefr6ylorBbP7ry9yPa4aC1HHVsQOs46Wn8yZolW6T48EyxYobH7M8MnM@jIOLBm0Hjl4jzENltJC2ZIMjQ3RCZl3ow0UsHoENacQCORynDrzNnpmaAbKKrDnrT9W9ZxfdJV2Ie0MYsnTGP2i3@Aexo@pspHnVIM5BmMQ7jS5xLuwuWe@kdYyrKmxsO3IMiXtrwsYRxi2jAR11sPwvvWv6ledsaxVBMGTFfedi5JiHxaBILZewqejKz33GcEX0AzNHD6M2Pmt/o8aMOcMfh7vxwVBkdEhl3opo4p44Po3WnTzTkM@TnQFA109K6wim/o5HiuaePk6PAINZsYFSQbAY2vknAa1Eckckm2QL21YKjPgunIngH4KxpjtW/iXNndUdDWTPxQ/RvE5VCCawoyIlQ7SZqI2WKfIziWBhyJsj0p@jB8P@BNJkBf512nAQ9ppYVBPBBlGSoQivavjJR2jfmosG63Yipab/6GIP5ag/MZdQxfXtzK/41RAI9OmPz4iOHPWxlZxAATI6DDXv@RiZplz5tnV6lHV0d9yS9RneQVXqtMEvFFNzcypnLapdr7lbww1GOnDVZDe5SVfVKNm7nPOtpyzSxlVePw7SAc0z8j/wTPgCJJjxz6aVYrU5yVkHPMiMHdKgla8FpRhGTSC39euet3RNlhchMyH5982UIRaA3gM90PzlRSV@JeW4y4iKvxOqIo@AhNDm2yVh8dMi6czbE7ASA87jJhyHIZTK6wQLREegcqi@GprKP2VAEjcRWh3GcQYhbxyPS8rJ6E2HPJ5Pg0Aj7455ExQ/kVMuU8CTAh8bQdpf31Ft/TCh3HtZtYbH8k8O@C9tFNCbHEro@8rY0@v0hqY4@@k04uu2x46kP@tAh6IVXQx2/kNaz9lCfSBiln5qB2iS7d15mJBw9oxa2R/BWaHrMH9ylbgALUQlPcptbUVliXsOjG@bQsX27WFTZ9fjLOtGEw5IyEdfVivryRUoJQXXI0IAp2A6jzQXbbHI7uHeIpt9Nf/gJaz9UoF4zaEaRSS2QfBYog1TrcYzHxki6PuiHfKJBQ4ETkIgSRTlIiwxVaY1@rtlJ2zWl4@iYiF3KPfn@diImNdZS1FDMuLp1Yr6VHA0mqLSkQ4NGwUKLS8uMyqwN19c7N2McLTR5ba3Sp71IpJREiSg/NqojnkRuRk8f8aQP@cuPQ8weeoM7bq2CAmHorLhXnZZzjB9sCj60g2HTPhMlTabpD3D8xluffo950Rwd6rB/DX8UBmPaATTy7ds8w6hn/9K/7NW3@h3/ot1v@7RPQyz5W5F4eBzzIwbsYti/CTklEX9oWoWa4/hZ4stIGDb8ju4l16zQXOEoGGRtM4XRcFy5lDARfHIOI8A4HSrz92AyRlpU59lyXCmV9D9le7yis3Zn3afFWZXlRh8AtIDbmLCgEB/SETsmWc6na1MFzu8rYOF4rnLKd@6w2Etg/IJIxNcwCYwNMlNmCXYnsDO7E@OT5q3b5BiEQwRaCrYDJNcJs/za9ZFhmqTIS1gKlFRxtWBVlVuUW8QhxMP4bnIvPf8HY08I/An0i09nccssRmAR1zLRlkLZr@goo4QLmwe2WUazJCYp1r5o9yz3Q85kcTsJNfl5fBc12PKHlCIdZm@KKzEjs7TxQea8bJ1ETn3sYFFZUAsOx@2AClIZZQt3M2zwLftZnvy4xJWTMwimLQ05ayF9F6kaRCXk8J0wr7VRlpjK354xS0sPHbUJApZnmZxZuaSzaaO5sAdKW9ZXXGv1hySM0xPU06YeC@GoP1h4IPXulB0zI7PNonXDcb5pCCzMVqbF8kmTSVse43G8lprEZ4JpkhRjSzPiIWxf@Tli80ki3pbrmG/l@vgbdLiLZrHdVLSoROPdlLmPRfEaFr1moYmmFOOOIKVr0fuTOnW8frcE0TBle1VniVGHyKiP5dECNUGmiEoPpxBzn8Z9gh5NohzabRLt7PG5k6iTRnIm5Kn5lAhyCXoicDucNkkuDVowvkCYONFwIyEVKZy37piv8oq5cwQZxgcBCK04yMXnUHKCGw/WBB9xdoBWtg5roSIkET1t2BYOUdD/iGAclV8f7miLh/o4VzxbE0i3ESTaVXCp@yAZf3P6eVK/ZShTpKApPoMUUY@mZNPlw3v1Z/tC5QiC1ObP2tK34KIzjlokbOgf@1P9Fjpw3JSumZhRyYlQZ9FAc4F2KRedQLar0P7aQ@F4WDfoaUQbCHmdxZ9FXQPhvFcKEbVR5bY5RhFHk1tmm6NyG1IlZij5DfLrqSiqLm9cCUAgGFP9cpEgIKwpY49LAQ69Y3NeAlE9RlSxXMS0pJccFTW285zxHUTVBZ4tWyUKs0q8sGHkZgIhxWJ2mRgR0llmF4mh0EI3ExerxPPZ/YlLkEJseF8oTkOhRyVJw2jkhICcvLrgxBLlpKjcguZg/vhs2Ul8jPibv74oWF8Lk1@JPhGGJ7ni5NfVQuJrotmlpWTVRE2ih2O3mvhIpHBshCOp8Of@x64pdsjzyCbU2mQktAxtn43k4rTLpH2b90uo1tkp2@gYBp7tGW62X3VJsZIIyn5/AHa1wFcGiN3@p3trLFMNJjpXAMelM84uWdkQssaaxlKPbmGnayLtRQEKzJ6231Lvj3Z2EmFfz8fG0KgbDJcLhQKY@NwOfm9sq3GU1O7nk6XzratOJz@4@cvw/XmeZX8QcEqAktlBBzQkNClCrz@8kMwQwIGKonROO7Jir3/VatkpGHBDicGjYZOSOhqC4gWoHRm9vD/iAyAGqRfYn9FB9O9nFc2@G18UTQ3FXENRbZgEX6fN7RmRBy9asM@ObqoYGASzsWaidcspb3zGCoLMJjxYHL7Y@RybJ6ffBJ1O31UfkNQYkQLmvk5W2NmxKxSkCG4Y2bv3KuR4tK4Krtsdy68YRWxeBzizMJk8EyYuPGLjHwQX1dtBNn3yU5qWFeryIrq5iPjUrkpfpB0dLP4BYIUPCe0Hle76g2yD6TRZmJZ6PYPjJ8LoadGdufdJFHH4TEzT7NulQdTZ6HocrIG67rAuYGLZ8/ByT@4oHhE3fXpbbIGGBYGhcULMlYfVgKvZP04sXo9arYdJRU4DIAP7XRJRMqH8OYHIdwA8A/X0I3oiivZfczStdyYCioiCg2Qd03IHFeqokEo9bpR/vclWKhU1P1hcVJXKJj3kcqqyWVHbeLG5qbbp9yZ@/1BeWl5eE5m77Xyml5vm5Ve1STD4hHOxcTncpp/0rQy/MVhrY4jn8@V5d22@Xl7fWAvzJ5VNuPXT03/@y//8z3/9X/mK/vHv@LHJP05@igp5npefb3ye/@HrGn6fbJ8tzJ@fzA/OFi7WwGV/46jh/doo58fmo97wPJWRVcB6y3akZp/N0Wd0VWXyBXb94SeSLiWVaYT5jH4bSuYolrGZRmC9D@BHeU5beJN0YHIrT0hkCOgYx/E0Oo0ABni03hAlCRfYgUp9uVsxB/cIBxMViG5VMjoSD@us1wF8WuJICvDFpRUr1@6FQQ8n4Nes80r3Uimf/rZHdc2/@Z/ehheb/Vv15DSrnhTUE1c9Saf5T3HlBb115vNteOdKMdoOpNMufYmvFmBmqMI2K3q8f@BcOxPkTqXmOWUPIJkwFVxYvODcaPfHzjKScC28SM0hn6eSIxK@ZEKVzOf53lcals9U4ms64WrDikJd72K4MetGJRpfqEB@KIYAcctdIUipT03ipo89kvGUN2/0WKc4mxADBlkPXu/wvMcLWovme9rmObGXQpojNp@Xt1gb18QZmtHGF2k/RoAvVGQ7WWBPwoXMQkqsvK1ecjfFC9vun2Y@sXUYByNjmy6VflcWE4g1t024@Z72a9GG3HK9otLt6HrFaio9afutUlaV7lVn1B5odwVuHRPqc9TaV5lJGFEGJHAkZn9peobxQYGJFDUxLJIsa6yafXRdZkJPu6bTADue3BxZRMj/lKW5/WVibjt59hIx7CA8wEhFpnwtv90JddSVIRP7wh@eIzug3@KEaiO5N@PzPORlncC434qQ9hgym5zH85m6khkM/Yuu76rMXv9o6I9rtGyR5jNqeA71ECGYgAQmn256VvcMwtIjPSRMkagrbDmE5AWdsU6PJmObjnxOMKRmKuiwK5gECXZiSgZfEmM1QceYq79jEGyUp4R3dBupRSxLXlgaaUhp222Gp9nU1EmZFuy5E02cdEpQjWam4QVd6QoLbZcvfkmSdxAjQLed1l6A2hVh5QXax@p0EfT8xOI06KSMo39@Tcm6iPnMqSjFGimloTwvxhnvgBXpkT8lo0DI2mTCGaXmstm501Cnc8vY6wgH@Y5s8fO@akcJ6DiBGXuGqONeW4TlxAoV58DwVI0t/wlCq@NfEH7jG38MVjzNZF8@yjsnP532zp5kT3tfTn9zGBMtks0qm1MZfZltJJaeK7Qy5t3ET2OVFppQg6e9ZIHTnhIfFosEhEg@e/JT/uxLnhA6zSDB/WlGCJIYMmCSv7@9PMDnp9DMJLHIZ1JzzhPHDH72ZdFRtLbyX4yhvHDkL2FhNpV8TE/7nGGLQLGf7q9X4nIS5leXCs@Wis9oJ3QR3OaGwRXW21x4dR7ckioRYjtLS8/pbwluSBDi623or9HLW@qnpDUR35NQOylpEaqnObeTitiK6njCE1SeqMzhUuHi4kRlfFw@YsPvKmI5U5ZjQYnpoMV9WayfYb@LdvwQcm3SO0Q4ElYGYiPCR6g5QDbJV@7iUMdMlwX2c/LUFmK3MhAa3nzGWi16/V5OK2uOt7AGJRpeM53Vwmphco5OTdHEDJ3XytTCI1XcePn8P/5t/9fMKLOxlP8wpL@jzK@ZldWMPNID/Xpqfl1nNjLrKLbyNTPO0x6YHp//x/@m@ht/ITj4Ml6nfzaWDayVcWYjV@YqXzIbK/RQXFqidv/PP/8z9WFedmzIxTpfdxUjtmYosuX3mHfpu6qhl7ItXYjFCjtmAYZYGNLenH7AMOp2abXAx3QZbVVxHejIV8YeRS/xbJg1YlMhOckw9hSkGUmFMhrICUhjQtFSlu2GMdsA88Zoqp8feysh7QB@1uYcUZOR6cbjECZD87ItogHMSou0n5eHjcLLdGTeUUobm5I1o0Jia6dl7erTNWKHd/1g1G4krSTMdO02/Jvg3AMfekHzivZUvbDT/2WYvyaW7BaXVvMtHO7n2Y47P2BIucHY@40UQZ0MiDaGbHTqqiGNQL@LEF4uZwsihX4nupMy@SRJyx4EDTnDSuYkpiLi4@fK9TC648WqdJb/JQUemTN1IkgrV9ppj2ruH5RUejEqKOV4z@sAm3dsHKtDYOTEGnbAsslLcR9wOmj641WGF@yExLUQdV2KeH6zWff1t2xqLm1SpbmpucugMyinWxLeHbFTcWOi6S9q5p1Qcm2cIORyLOgAqxuMfNqil9P8BvvxuAWESdF3rVGouJisLV1W7@qbZc66ck/TN9L0DY0otIS4nYhnrGhsyi4msqWMo8phUMeV2syGqbXQJG0eevwHGIQyLLUW3BJ0d9gDkqgWd0dbldnD5vJemHjkJhCfPTlalMzVqUzs/OiaEuJBDd0J7XrSGAkIRMEtwUKZfh@KB0TZpBlt91ISz2/is4nvocFwH/YRStQOWyfBR2VZ6l0j9017xL6Uikig48raNtgpWT0i0FGIrSgFbRoHL2kHLNUq8WaLC5rhKHEaaBMSKp2Wc6qThorSy7Z09lpJFEEv0oXi0tNnyyvPV18gy9mc7u1sMKjkYRcwuPQJBmvUWdpk4325nF5IyyukoJ5uEtBngcUFHMy6bhzHhH2@cR6ViwUNrJBmWDecRkOq6@NKBhlDHAYeVgTao2SH6Wz2ZekEHTs7bTpf6D/ibxMfkBnOhKP1hfTWOLyLI1OluhJwoMyCmYPiZJ8igoqjv9hlg37rANEmAti6CttTQ7uIADG6HPavLi5t7vB0aKsjmjBEcI5LjR3U62AUBxizsIIuqg8capb3RdnAO5nuAYxysSRA5xPgNM103EpfW5pidizQIoTImvBYxRWiZTpqszNzZ6@vqnvbk4hl7DR0DNezLVtJueNIZgggg1y9VnePiLo62gW7kmqZ5CaiKrOAK6Bckd3hffhKN5CI2qKKkdWsN4yy95GlyLwYhzaNq9I4Aq8ZMIuFb5PS@LWaXoAgRhDq06RIiLnRfY5Nshgne5AxT8HL6ZJlI/q2HYYcYE43lna0RSkX4qwCc6k7AOLcppCWjhRKGFF@rHLiZRltJHMUr2gcDWgz5GinGswsyWkm2Oo2lADYyDpuaIH@1/a2XLVdpX92Pmy7UJQ3K39Fv6MUz3fjW9T4FkuqtmOGwI4Wyza3sJn6FS5KxCwFHTA2RhDCtyVZEYM4akC1tqNpL5P6JDG3z2KuALv6Wgk3p6N6kiDQC5@BzOnNexSKg911@F1JDq@mJU0UUkVPCzniun9iWzSZi1uNIAkpHwBiaRJEFKgl5va5mOHFAp01b1/vXQxj13Zm83SCZWVDRWr7Tp7InuTZOylzH1ssabZYKmEc7@ML5tt7eeM8aPW1L1rEHN/gjUd/jDdyD2eO3H8L5qj@Y7jjqeaOpyXIHuGOKGw4e3RyGvb@DI45H/MaXG@2L9o4H2pZP9GJgmsBYIEHDOFDSh@LBfTtDnGisrM/LE6uRzASWlqGY8Af6vwz3flnJchcftwO/qt2Pvd37vyy7vxyCWvNjJHXqp0Vbv3v0@NYJcwmX8wcXqi7Usz5oz1d0T1dKWE1nTHM/997mvt/1NPnuqfPS4iYIBcOEr7@fm4WTaRyuFWrxeYWXkoH7coij/1srnSw92qW07R5aHWuwssytHX1h/Ff1fivQhrxE9LQ4S4isg2N9vKyPRVnedEs@ZRDwclKeiL9NZHRrf7qBSvej@gFSoQ0H2wN9UaFFHJXPsa3TV6sP8bSN1p8HoqzyHadLBMX59YGWnaERSee4qL56iSZSyvRurLNMZDV1tHB7uL/EDJ0/U/aC42Qx9DeBJ2OWUnsLdhRFHVKd8bqDmAf6j1HglU0ORnZkfb2jthl7m6pxoEtJtbF2ZsEuWrD/R/tpbrQN6ys3DgyItp4ur7ZVcE012wv5A31XQrN7rLu8R/i0heaS1@U1IHeGNxFKl8f@GlejPdpS8vL960BUsvDH0zAgkvl75lV/xc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/8ih7t)

Rc/Funge is separated from cfunge with `0k;`, as described in [rfunge wiki](https://github.com/tjol/rfunge/wiki/Undefined-behaviour-and-known-bugs):
in Rc/Funge `0k` skips over single `;`, in cfunge `0k` skips over command after `;...;`.

```
'@,,,"285"z;@,,,"366";k09<
```

`z` is noop. `'` is for fish, `9` is for YABALL.

Answer (score 3):

## 398. [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers) v3, 16625 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)1 1>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                 2222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&11# 11 393374366369375377370285329364392367372376289368371388   389284373
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
























































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::PrasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t"F ._#^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4oya:nlet d=/;~       ^ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'7* 001- #vk!>6*+'P:3+'D'34#v({d5da2220-fa93-44d6-914d-3e4fad3beafc}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L39c@NKciD448TA@0eUQHWTFAmAAL9JkWq1Wv1ab7pbPWr1e8@PZLNBEiTRAgE2QEpkS@qYmb2b89jePe/seGM89vqNZ8974/NGrG/j9jy@tXcj7Ptxw7E/@Q9of1xcOC48/8FcZhYAghIp9RuvIzbuIBGoz6ysrKqszKpCoqN7w5/9LIYXe@ZY84HlTNjE8Cas55qnhiuz@3N2Tze9vJYVBEy16w6mI8OeeBUhxlTGLN0eTPWBwfqmNTHcNPMMg3UMyzmDeI2x7ak99YxeHXxZxmzjjB3YXbMHENjEOTFs863hQlyOsQeGdTG6mLCuMxrpds9jY9e0JxSbZ@yZDp7@tHvC9I43cfXuxHRsiCow9sK29FGnpzNKPnYNnqnIAFT3hPIsx5QYe@K4ngElOF3D8xwMLEOg7prO492nH11Jr2bYRzogNbaM2ZXiVZV9ahpu72oOjX1y/PDh1dAs@5rk2OzhdZTUHNudTpyDyVX4ebY7MGydaXJZ1q5GFoCYE8MqZUqZq1FFaE9jYnaXyoGIh6YLrav7rci6ug2thW25xYzReDJnEm9/3bLCtvWY7rGpN9UtSmdPRx3DDRJ6E92dmPaAnZmTIZsMTS/MR6m9sd41pJ5hmSNzYvSYZUImp@9DAdB2j50Y8zPHhSb3YTq2NYeMRtfsm5glwAMA4pWYDA0OZ6TPoZHtCXQOpjMP0LCMAFpSiEH6B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjg1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadaBOCAyhZ8NDdvvzABOBhDHDsfq9ZRQMxZ9Xu/1WAb6MeBxYjATqEZoVVg2C@HMcYFqkCrAyAdG/ZrX0ZhBm0ET9Z0Ky2cyEL8fhiC2uuU5PjLLqGGkDWOV2gzhPnOdgauPgBo9g2j6ycEz5nUdF3zww7R8PN0EpqtP2PY2i@8/fRBn9bBZZLcjhE1UY@fQBLEgkp3q1hR6SLQlHGgfN8wtYJPFN@IVFgeyaBmWy7EcDNsS0/JAJDVTBgeMfy2rwq/AtBLLqTCC8iyrFeNpLKvv6gPTMjikAUIqYueHJBrcMzmWVUs85cCx@jxZlwossmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYMSEXyOqeU8/ArwA2hlQEeFXzbHAS36PvRV7G97rK@PTGvuQyfwXZZXWREgAs4qQNZKAAGe2Sz@svAjtJavKOzJECg@1E8BvGSZJ8iRjJApYTMq8FC2thTiish2efHeEIsH8gHh8iVWhOILQIkcoADU1UpQfD7DK@INDcvysw09zEbYFjPwA8yLQIcStEAGaJlBYhbhB37geRowNw04mQbMSQOGomngzmIRkK4AcQVozoJPr6HunUBBvBytR8QHrg5gVKQ2MjIViQQQoLVYFtqswHLQGbLYGfJZBvgDLsUCA15WUlkpx0pFBvQsZxi0jQp4YU9RgYeqgI@KwKD9VegAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjzkzUJeII2agzw5cEPDqQX8QT7oGSoUqUKZmlZedETATctDffNZ6qFaAVq3CHFANw1w1aA7aYCtVoJ4zFsCGpawA0O35YTQkQ7QKtjloR8CMfKAD8GFtODWillOP90aD/UOcmyes9PHrAUcCgUkI2TNYPXgmUNqAioZAIOjANDXoAdkacTAMxcWb6kApIHgjZ5JTNoygX@pIYWKaeqQr/XxZEE2tUAYjeeTYRim8TAHmKcJDNAY6N15GAmjLx1GLkILWQzViN8uAGVyGOoBd3WmnrUAEjpyGhVlnJrWIqxEYT1D7/VNb/hugWuOCukY@sQ2Txal5PPpCFH1SEQBI5aCitlo2okpwZQ1GKJrURetiGnGTthASyirKqHXMfpTe2BI5VIEP4qZTN0JTC6LMss82DUHA5iXF3DUNFWTJstFcJ4wtLLZiRAGInWxTNeEKfwu6w5BqAgjyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4MwugSQGM0EZ566@OWOdu12aORYIZolO3aE5DhJX1iaONC4VMisVIn2DKPe2lAlZM14t@bVj2ok4iyeFSwHmGy5dRmdrmNQ@xZkK517sujC3OiQ5LNhnwg5mxyQQbXmih5nXAjYKjdLVcRbGOcmgOTWAY05kBoWAKGg4pyi60sS4VIxHk2fHRUkVJJ2e4boM04J466VpmvWmHc94M0VZaoFXH@ZtA6b3vm5aIQI0j@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@mAWlsVEz2nv0iGxhAdhBa@6ihYpdfVGA8pioQKXSbC7S2DpTCKnTHcyKLEFvk6DuOjOE9x/CoszjuSTj0sTDPGNDQgHHWXzCjEQro0EttUix6wHn84YXwsUBhZWWwKL8XfGTYMHS60Cth0EPzYZvusj4o2hERFnUNvds1xhO/nzjEzkw7IvMfPkSZn0IlH5jsDYXNe2z7Sq@BpGHPiciyqAMh6mNfFdGR1/ravESCR6h2cs5iza8VDylOr5QuvsI0Sxi8EtfgMKYhgQoQMYnpBFkJckezO0ReOEFuQ/I2jDZ3er36EBYt3h0xqR@WjdiowHYEWQmDEI/1MCT4WdcByWMLYdWXAjDpUsAtoHVvtAKyEyJp9aKhsqLLwBRvAzpybGcFVCBmCBeTLMdQW1BnfI5cQ7fCzkjDxVtqI2TYiwUmnMhgDh2PHRdGBmc6c1pNoCaL9C5fCU@Ec0VSZveXp1aYMuI44U9wFoQMY0uHvoBDDEcqaFY6cApgYlxJBp7n8BIjCNOoJ1g@fmfE@nlngrnUtg1UznR3zoFA9WB6hoLmzHRdYIOnOEnwOSiYTGTqpzAn6L0eclYkB437q4XL2KP3ph1zdlUT72Kg/NoTTnWX9VEJd0HogEGUiPe9eLJK4ZQzEiUqzniiUFZ@FyEhJZKhyRN90OthkngIjOb53O4mxKUhJqaZOJ30S2ISHJiRy2jsY1AVrmKH6gN2mtEJjGvyVdkApm9JgruEYYQJRigyRuguyBkwCEHLLJd7HZ1dAPdwmTTb46pIoJKoci4sy7B7YVk@IRCXaH1lXoTndskhRWY1rAEmp5rTJLFEwA@kBGUUIUBR/LkVA0ja43Ek1/DAqU1rcSzBRZEkOw@FX5gAEoSMCcKH2TUnbV9cuXs3EFw2ajXobCBNAdvsJaMabbBoKQOnhsQySSN@IfLEeT7BsZFIQn0x8SXHBsQm6Km1OjufDF0YceS/FCARkFWwsScHhPXb@al5Mu1dbWgbAzGRiKMOhCazOxGrAkz@fDTUbqJqfImqoPXGkarYeTE/gb7WeSkUG1T0k7mGh@JvzUcl0sIJxMDvqytJxLP6YYsOvTfvWr5IwF0w2Dk36gD6J/5iVsiI0r5MEAzaayOVA8HhwOGwZ7vHj2r@WOSRSse0K0sBltPVLQrexORikPfxwf2j3aNfbK@AYZmdytUAxcyVCjjVTmfSwJ4qOVmrbEZhLAA/aN8MGzMupxEFP5pJziwiKs27MLnMAnIeHn3tKklAEkJyUAngxt8VkYanAaFL6Oje8MokzAapFBQZZgnSMumABTBDB6KO8XqAz7Pp27fYeFeRGvvhiJk11TmAIFA5sIN8MkZeEcCCqE6fz4iUF6RQ08bNhoUrmjLA5yOUmq8iQ6J0pMt8dPhw/6hGYP11NYmSKN4EZCnd7cnQ560pqOCr0gD7A1eXpeQF4ihPE64rCdztLhF40bZsDXwAgLqO7DDJGgVV84aA@97VulGo1A17APkJwlW5MioPdb8sohE8cIrrosq7ahaliMVkFQatnLHC2OVpq5vPG8VcOTptdRdl9qJAaWMA5oFAbnQh6sSTMEReSJG@WO2j//zxNcQ9EiJBFZACzDyLyVSWZwmovUgmi3vKHmhojmXInxLHE5mYVJR4sDcgdz1SPiPp92fmJJFJ8qeahLRQ@u7ugfYgSOwvWdNKBikNqIvjzOT2cY@v60EfsR3LGThsC/Jw6TAoEMSmtdXcHTj2tRbSMRCrGsNtQuC/uHCjj2GuMd@S4ki5ouoq33DUbe8MuLRayCKRiEIESqH08mv9VAdyLer9/ODzfZhE1HwmE7ozdAEJInmIXOjqRkIpgElQkOzjs7KC4ZbhtdEeREiRPTustM/owoy7i@iVgcQxZWVl@pUofexco/hrZ36la0EI71rgiJDs4OmzxwdP95/sftacaPn8kj@XKReAcFBeB2QhecjphqN1iw9NrBaCi8HYcHF4AReYgoIS7BhNPRcYt4xJZI7Aml7DN1sTHztDO@4lr1bmDGOl13aXd6EnOPh4Uj8jKNo9C5URl@9Y43yO/Wc4mYy9iqLAKB9OOzIorcrrrmPpA4XywcRgWYqKqsvBIa5reKtyADLe3OA5@OIWiA5zWkHUrZEDygvteyNrYAkOnlatLHMwBF0YN8cNNymHPZhqo/RAQwBdWQnrRgyYfEBb/xm0k8i79ldVrcT7tZrRcooYJFsa/pB2o2@A6pSA2QpIkbziZc27zbtsDlwaIV0FEmPyFi1yeAznAouBIEmrpqjnB8QhboHrpcgriEZvpriaC1xKyWdyRbWQV0AtAzUNZFYJ19ykkT7pDqWJIwE8yenTukGkF/a9rm735S3fESALct8dqGq28bLZtFsgoDfvEm6499yYtxpqK1ll17Ns@emTVei9S9XDvhsEQN8lJ3RNerI1/KynX2dnPZ1GV48pk9HYn3OkMXuyC4LUWwf4dc@Ijj3MoEQjla2ltAomfqesWBCyMKuAN6SUAgMKZlroegriJYHQi@Ih9BzgW5EMbLGaEQpM88kQ@EeWJfbIlbwu4WJw1ucay6jgorA8ngPLo0TItKUsIhREUIFjDgFRiYMKhBIPxsc5CvyYSYSVod6PQ8904h5t06BohQu23hjakda7uzhReLhEOYEJOhx8OFFA/8J5gp0ZcVzK1z2@YAqZ/KMGQX5QF0MItDEQLorb4eEK6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV2@FioRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBBj0wbGACoJmXlFdnlFeEkUslylE9s5sxFax2AlqWNO@H6DM3Vxy93sResGybMaTwPQqHKRqYX25jtGly/08sxUC9BDdTYyRg6uZoCAR9zIoCrofF8f1VEPF81hZGck3LQE@BK7tweMtGvwJStphHoc9Op9Fp@4yq70uaJLb2FA3SDeYeUjTew3@nFAgOVTFrRQ4y/CkoDkjCjRp7Tkg5H3A4nb71rYs0S95owN@6rayZXSRLJKpyHicb4PdR7f2NiIV@L1eBpcO@DaRtcOulLg2iGXRC5MJ6OLcqTJhbENyoFhrfhlI4A8S7awD8xQeHlrjhN6o1LJttJ6Q/WfGj6T0BRAeUgt4QPgxJO1GjqTSbF@httGoEJE6r6Hfed51zXHPgk@BpmE@6PDS/SHl2tUUT2@mSKjmgt6q4FSbsKNNxuZZqt53uylmpfxNOZOVvUaqKjAPyeJkTxwnekYZMdGriIBe002spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsqAgPZm8U0qmdE7rRNyAPpVoNuNAUp86je7QJXiztJZMhoQCPPomKDqWlYjL5yUov5NsJVNxyJuMp2FmqMXjQBfa8/So0rgowTvRQ3MGpISBCbNsdFuDeDTtj@Fw/dwYD@duNEG48AeCPi7iL47M4MkinEiijPotzx@VKZcWGwLRm6cD@RrXD1FkG8/5BCNwTJvK0gGtYOo/lfojZ6Irn8igt8mRGTu@EVckCSZjiuGQqNpPTA@HsG4bztSLLnauXIPF0iH0eDgFZhmckktDrzLHgtEdOiy@eQ@gs3DLCRk/7p5JfA8uANDryvBDJoqCEe7XgIBD55pM4It0IowWhlRCgrOeYHsgXxi/kcPSqpSHZbAgc2A7riEBSSCHQIe46GigUA@2xg9o8e3a9OPH0qyKU5lpAEd8aDk60Zaz68iW1HgUyW8PMMuR0RMs4B99YI8ybwvX6ClbAm0UO@4QZgioDXJiLWytkR@hON64J09mkFVI4JwfjeQKJsi9Z6ynaVqhm@9XgjjsFUDsITQSKsY2aNlBlKRCZNJv5H2@MhUsEzw9fLDPl29ovscZHpfy2iOnNwXR1lfdjgx7kGb70J9M2xmZQIYg/9sT68hxJnyhATzrFoe43m6OppZOy05XV4ZuzNd1Oo5Fq1E3ZV2kn7qebul8HSyI3f3kCagbL46f1@RKJJGin45uLBuXQlcXy@l5EN32pC3fYIfK4x1T3MyLOG8Fh0@RzfgRBYyY@kdPoY2C8CKGB0MKt3H88BKGj/DYKYjr/kIGecNAP2GZEuJRVDx35weeq5lLDF@rBobpVErHZdcFtueqRuGnk35/KThLwScSsiZrEZyjYH4kdUlNjaKU54nwfOpSmiigAqUJj6muTVekdPyAjRxubj4Jz0EMDSvY3TwCiQV38GDSt1CuAr0JtQR@lNQAIX@MGzXEunH7j3VBDvauSbEw2MYSTy3ENmgAweSmoEgjbCrMX36v0hCyHX/b1ONs1XHTfGVnu8432lGtc7lGqfCNgc02gNiuV4Mzf@uSYUnxeJiMoBJukIOqSWcLrlU1PCni0Xq/QFmqgqeARjPTMlJzVtxvXcQVj8jQZ2KzObuT0T4D1QgPbW7eVQZGlY5ZraFXNYiJ@zJsZ84kkPgwFV877w6Bz7DUbJmU0D5Tu@9YPYlv1EGHYVzFwwbyz0mEh0n9M8OG6QbnSOkgL8@K/DVyBPUa3CtNWr@eIHJoNQQEw@ecXZykTy9YA6a8U9kbW@akxS7lidMe@oe17KvHW7kM6rr63BP8YzY1tnv00SeNTItDEEY6br6VeCvOglPSIDiDoITH2cGFh4Um5oQkAToMYWJ9VRmQmtE@DaAPMHgBVRYW5NcIUb8wLhZ16RugLCcMxNybj9LMSF7KfUufTAyb9zm@A7qe3Hyryi@mRsXv@PseFZahzSGQTE2MAxSr7Pnxg/2jIxl6rpeI7@MmUgWGo94dgoCyrtIBJaOVr7A7vTi7g3mSuHIgwFAD7aPt54dOXYVOD/oHlI68Y2C4CQhM4v5PF4Jpy40ycgnNJxAe@epOiEYhsISRhDoRsMpK/F/YXNXy8axAj08RJYHcibsVoK2ZlKe2@Ub2YKIhuRWS@MoqzBe1zQRxsU016Z/pG@HuNWhYJDRCDRoNJr0FLgeJRdZqVfkxBEiLCpg7QOqKIjUFHaavqUHT1yAYRBqC4GevvWMvGxmp3EptrgJF59v8c/C8/hG4CGEZtGesLHYzQeP92kDmOPDtSM65X5A6feUlkArb5A6RL3tT8uDMFjEdOuK1fFRr@SAYDDJkJbQahBUJWELMf0vB77MUT5wfdB7MRgGJJDsPia4hydnFBdGQbWqMaAgulfHGuAy0T2BMjx2ozWP/DYWodECj1T/LgmO2KYiBmrW8WYwxXIRXTq9Ip9KpGM3HpUPTPnFoyyl0tTOymkeJMMw9OrGu58RzsHRbShriwNNq67DzRp0@3VYkoJ0Xf0@fAmhN35eFQYjUlSN60PL@ipKXz7EsFeufkKWZFtxMenNLSqlcosT9TsdclxSIgEfTgueKZMCksD9rck5Wg1cecCkG5iNgXFx7WVT96hEotkR3/yiv//zP3@gB/a@3zhAmClz8DB1tmLqxpaT@2sbys6KHbqsblq/RTy1TJ8KQ6zaQXd2FKulW6FgNms4BSBJM/yPc1fBbHPom3kBqvKGbccz5pmTwXF3Iqn09G1hmd13aK0fCeFG0AwWKXY@IwIUg06BMxLp4IxgzvgsUUbGRjd2OVHBui1Fn5u0@nE6m/A6C662NaI7xd9PY9FNm8npHNRR@eP6GJnf1k2nPkcYng1BOLaxIu6g9bUNLIA74O9JtdK6uPq8gP4wePNclW0xtyhk9busVnj31xlKHtPAe99FAGN1Qgmvx@7okpv8OYehYTzXTotsH9kQfOnQU/0CGgsddpQjRzCtktvTOHGWQ4ZfvZeHhBuA4tW4qlcmu2d0ej9fnR02S8pfLq3PP5C6nx6o1AoUfqZX4KhpV2D9ke0urwnRljnRL0noR51pmvupsxLWk4bYq5cH3P@glkBs7OU5I3amluwvXDV18gUewjbBuRdqfNp6ZXQfEgTFTi7KqBVNHZMIglhmczlsUhCea6RY5gWGuImPwRosUulazAKc7wVOra/rUBzA0floUz@RGOonsrKNU1znD31rxYQiqKb@vntHersTqA5iTZHUtHebxtdPB0uIgLj7e0lHPTM@g22rCnqxEdNK1VoYvD4Fg2S@6jHdbt/ZMy/HYc7rfRKCBC1Tg99UdOkpLU7clWgyPum/gQcExi0WD6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2rT90@8n3/@aEcLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3NRC9M@niEduI84YpdhWb8vde1tcOFAPcuFtds4eZEuWUFb7Ut6Zg3HI50@fB8@eYOtaRNpg6xnMSp0G6wwzlEjgmLhexf57ScjeX1vswpnQNbPG2SkQa98QyYLKi@7UmZVpG/ZI51Ezmw1lU35oaU2OlonHYeW3g2/03KBkfjlTGr8amv1KPmwP4dkyY6q2vGX4Q1jhPo@9GZqJbZte4XZRZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdFzPMbCn46VWXdLO7KObSTYcB0Pa6S1hhzFflg@VbpGUluRzz6DfjRoT1/DwjFotn8lkfAEmsuOy5LlJk8qGeV@b/L5UMIUsSl6kxV02N@JcXQaRJXoKci0L0tYp9pS4XFZs0zYmc7x/IDftOI71ZVoKmCq@s@yAtirRad@bWuyauOO/x8IWSxceLnh0@usWLfhs4@uWQB9Umm9q9OiW0Ae1poSbniPckFr23rx8E9lguq0UfL8W14T4@V9rvSzpr4aockku3jjquITqdAxL549ZIXcTvLKcvRHeMtPwN2txc5dv6S624mNXmNJ4DsQye6ClDI2RQd4bpHy9h5Y6/MfaRDMHf@uiZ4bRVWb7RnddgrEJfMHG@9IeckRYmjg26FcTPGqIeoqFh1n90HUcONj1W0nkg5E@MLjpmJs45WLBAk/TcLVu4Vy9dFHhJ2i6kG1hE2R9l4BBdWLMveC5EuCTeRfadTq6fbntyuDv4hroB4z2dador0@x9tAZ2kNjyI@uh751gwP644Sb@rkJdcB6MMTTdOPx0in7KD0tx7I@hJ7IGjmjdJz@Spz28f1bfHnsS8HlL/v7j1sX7/QJ5x3oWDtqhsYU5iXPmThjQyLfuqQWLvTw@zoeGmxS/7wrSDfq@UCR4Pnzwr9VtxzozmQ8pkd7bE09ulFWiV6bvk1u6vOjKXQu03EH8ltn1JH9QNk/t0Jb4KtZTMecdIf43jrv2cbA6XSH5m1I@7YylGDJh3s/SHdFyphMeoDBsmUCed25jP2lFo1/jo@DdY3urx7xaS103CCvrFqhozfDpbF@0vX4aii6WAUXhCOjkb8/XqE38CtvpuZkATRylilc3uXbEuhYh7t/emKtZEWvaSzYsH@qYm0vJSEdBXLJyIDAo64rdvmcW2SIZbP8tg6haC0Jo8i5lC9Dbv/sD60OmpF1Wwhf6l9Lh5ZWTnL2cDrwrjNMvlzfAxENb@uXLeg4dWTJGuYs3fYf68isWQq@ZwnPNshcU@PGPZX8jZsqlE61JN0x4dGGBzTddO0ammWOPX5nUn/tVpx/lgl08av7hZw289XKtN8wPaPPt0DQdZuIOHJcPIkMMojUxZ10XEFHZs4FL864bGcATF2y2CJxkHad2LLymNDq5g/nTOmzp8ZAx7PWj80JHtZc0Suoy646XnQr7K9Pdc/8@hRqtq6zodEIvg3pRq0LoG8FvCf6wOw@WmqIEEmfwP5JT/5Y6v4YdL0tzoamhyeaQscNC1PY5Xgnxl7XBr1hRcqr6/ahvYzFAOJvYq5MvWpt3RnP8YW1ObluWlY3J7TK6j/XqY7rDoHdiMTZdDSeev5jNQ50Ziq6Cj06oXDvzATg0htgrWyoW5PVK9WRJVeQwvxJceFcJ41/blrOgH1eyjAQ2kAIQ@F8Rce5D9PzMzyQ49oreiKV/YHbnrjQIbm8Ym@gbQ18r8I2Jzev5kwmeDgneGJl@MyBbygoj/Eu3/uyEKTj1RR5fLusv3g7@pb5HXrec2fqdg10hiZPomqBX6qxF5w@xjc6HDTZchbV0rqOBcMLHNbKIdN17OlEcqf2jbNC4cZZoYIGryLdgCW@vv/kRTLaG@i09m1SaGASbeFae2DgSiczbRDE1vPR5dSBLvGAm2o6oqPCt@TZRXtSXWLXD5xV@s6zOUwgH6wwAfOfjh4YXdw2vLXsp84Tx3ZgNhoDoxwdGdzswNJBj9UZMdtjfLEe6NO7tZjnBHbNJMSlDX1sdKB9rYXrQ@YiDviBPtHXTEW0Nkj6X@i6ta@YVsdwX9OiX8S9TqVdRuiRMSPdYn2H4WNQmnS7XCTG9bilMbK0Y@ONHcfmd@K2GXioT27mKjAV0O3DN8plPIi/tC6wUj9brurhKT8lYvS4XYx1dXWNjmPx@w1nkmyTnwnQXdPwlMdoZoHCCjkmgfTl3chDijfykIVqBJLsqe7RJv1qVWMBUp19iSNAQ93tOrgT5jtuOJ0TsY1wC5sOz/bzgwMdIPwMOJbenfr2Sm9Dyxp1RnRbqzBEWvPI6OBbQR0yKDLRZ9cbk68M@dYUIie6QhsEAbvCQV1giWegjSRvn7aW9KhlqppjuhGnXrtdTod1JNs0um91XDVziF6LtemleKiz8pSca9aqI8OIVpEVnV62XzmSlo@ugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xuWt4OLL2s2A@ZjgzcZF7ehVkrujrekCrrrN5PD5mra0i@uUHgJaHpQS4fSrtrJU8ED/@H9z9WYBJuF3KB9RNgXbfv4APyU9f2Hx/SA5853qRvzg4Bb3wLYB07wWrlIQs8@MhA19a6SkDr2VOLrz4MIueuRj1SxyQyBi1JFrHriSEZ9qlEtuhm12vk8Je@lF00IDwxepJvigF3GqTHwftfYTL/uWIDNcob8bCnqnDCzgo5//jnKuKeBZwB5C1nIo09eipj79nB48NjeeypK@en3SG@HXFNjluy7aCVMpElqde6G9nv5MfReqY3Ue4/V6W9xwcyJlhDb76jIcEDd@aWHmvXPQNDsoq@VgvCWGOyWkB8dPzkcWrxiiZL7A1dZ2Qko9F7z5@n8U2Tj5@vjI7mfgijo@/M1mY/2FfV5Iru@8Km3cF13HNFSesgHRugjUJnfMRNw9wqXHWdsdE7no@NT2DyRA7ufWDxhbWVfKqfmgMchay8llA0UFlZLuSSkZPZoGwbbvhc154n5hi5ZZceCn@sPY6CkkNWcbOrpYebdvyvSjEs459E@HKZ1Mz13ho1Zazo3t8XMVVV19H5ud6HdmX5tY21nGDV/rDlnH7AVrLhKy9SGCRNoFdJ5q3nyIvSCFi3gjdcnvcDwdlZewzmJgBhcGHlgD8z7LluS7SXdZN4UYHceKjtxiSfGx@wIRWe8DlFe@kr9/jCI/Us0SVn8paCj91Ilr29@we3ZTjyaXlzqo@evmDPdA/toNycMIqx8QEYLySj1xKuW6ERvrXbqT0XQGk3whuMV4/nCnuuuz3Hns9u34Sjd1Bxaif7xiEs9FEiwzJn5qq5qsvXtZ6tPmZ0W9n8JQ5nviQHR@3j@IDef/ufqWomQ9aP8KlmuPeWlgkGOEugS5@jSb1o1PFByBq6KLfIEJBcqY0@NmZ4HIWvBq9S6lfOb4Ub5r5icv10clNc6Ya43A3lXYvDQJaVM@oNAPM3xLG8HEY/dqyzoSPv6a7hrTh/vBKhmypSvqEi5Qh39g2208ai714v4uOrC/5jZW89NiZubjx0OmZuZR12@2jnkj1Be@3X4/3jFLpLx1sGjv/KB/evLu9saqws6In@dnUEcZqTlVHABI3hlF6JuB69vEHaAZnXsAcmN/HI7juTffLdoJiFbzyvPotgjh9Mx@sxBt6IX8W4ys6XEn4KOrNz5rH7@GrcQkxfofvj@bjV4etkWhYuDKKl00fHu0HvOnyuaJESF1h89mwpGF8enRw@j4S5xmy2TumVZut0yJUxi1KfHueWit2uvzxdQaz17xuBuAH8OHyulYM4s/v4@XWWgOrbcDKygpiPdXuxYrrUYD1nQm8arox8Np/RMcqVLT3kp9hWxbndFcFLij1MyKYJZXtKu43mmNrtdb3y2PiM9h5ADGITLpZwoL7hJWOWGwYYUpa1A9U5WQg/S@g@Hw9Ne7YyarQuD50iTbz2Vg@DXfbccs7Y49Cq0Dr2oK0Grp8a9jrmtOplRamcvVkKy14Rqda1C/@Aiv9Y1yT31wlqV3gGHoi4iZtg/qOu8jDwfKIlb03/8fMg@e1p9ywH1@975nR0e2ICm0rdntC9gf1dBWjengy/N3IydFz79qRBd6pU7hsfiMTGB6cczbvOB@DQ6fdvT7TvObcnejK1JibqLKuTPnWmFloQWBW37w5Whte3682mXJHXRaJBd2/oJtfH47lIZ@qBDmSGzDPMKL02J0uBQZ@JhqF9ecOWbSd5Be7HDvsaWpJfQYq3H9hGHz9cl255w2aKW/z0RvDCue5Q73ievXWQvzUH5PmQQWeboxvTLkz@HbiOzX3JddPjwvzfipIe6ZZ5K0MLDjxotxx9wAmNx7PT7HWg/K19YPrRj054ad9mF7dywW0LeHLwZZBEwoa@kVz@DFvUUAKaZk9somniTTKKAGkvLtiGb4gAIsTAtIFvegEtmJr21EDbCfzjTJPaJhRTq6n5MtvB755VmJqhMvFzjmVuKDIorME2z32zApWKesk2akysiMw37BDafee2ywEwWl2GSjHpRGWbE4jZDIwSMPoMD7tgtJYqddG4LfhkJWqepeqbbQCcNs@fHTzbf368e/zieSPTuvTNOgS1sG0oLTAecyfbE6HyPt1AR@NfMiBzIhYUR58IwjVYL6gXw8@OLVettlS1RaXEHcyzeW7bikKWLRTpEvCTRF4axaKkAUEcdlBjaiDfqEmFG5kgWxnQRhy0SGVCo1VYZlXBYx30jU3bj7/6lT6KxS85VvBbjliwb3weeuLAcXp@iZ7Bbr@CEh/uHjx@cbTPAgQXvebM7E2GtXKef5uAW9uBduqbdNS3xuJ@lji0Va0WfxgHwsTlOKuQLRL6LgB0dEgWUAetmPi5t1hik@ADBeNhoyj/@RvKZVzGt1aSkDYeIBWHYqHPU0fZ2Nhgx9BJ2IOjg0/2jxjiv/@AgpFECIIdoyGEP/txj39ZJzBUFnzF0h2RckCGnoSoMZTAQsjCiAnSnMbueP23LOlLNmQqJPyETvgNMEGgLyxBvz0jM6dX7E8mySQc//ambx40KIi6UPA1DtwgRVOfyHZMz0RDJYhDHy1vLnd2PFNJBm9ltosf6sTPger0mSdAfWpPuHU738ZVDHqaHPKcNNskZPlHocRIwvj2BnT2jgF6I/NsE2auSYW9hp6Im5AVbshGkurxa1kC0BVySahrRBJeM9XpKU1Xef9r/0QZVBm4J@D@ju@eZe6D71d8Xx/cv8rdLxXsaNdNey5wiSKEFoH9GnBEQvoj7SPfJ7W58aAF4dACacBYmTmCZjolqmNyXgK/S8CPF3ASjU@g0aC7QYv5RoN4eYbbSqBJ4oqiYJfCtQyZJmBjxs9PXzFNXMgXcqoCSEqnAUD6lsgADUNwgMlkBYaJcGqOa69AP97e3mYiLmgatUKVt6yyab/Miq9CRDchrQATHiDXYJAHsixyQFzdzwazT0pNYlbkXnE1joyr58C0RPE4faHf9gkhsgQQi9PIwI9TzPBTthMQ830T2x38@GvkO1ObPiBJhTmJXElR8M3tPHUm0H1gkC6@JMfN7eD7A3wKRMOxHv/AM1m2xv4oXx9ZCysRwQet/LEmIw/goLKZq7NptG3FTxHEcwRREVd138ZL1pw07ZbC@yaDbvrDFZ3ZBvcvK4M1fZbXe/e6UeHEVZPASCx277nt4MrtQ6gMS2iKllXUQnJRpVxuZZX8GvnFQHXQctkFFAdsClhG1zBfO2Nvd2//4OPDZ8@vGc6llPGryYDv17dTTUlON1qhIx6t1nKT3H@oPH9y/2HQEAukCxFuDIzfr4l6U00WGzIIcvGC39WqrcLwau3WY/wpNwFyFd@sdhNqlOkaHmrmS5RLL9lID@lV2auFa6VV1Mrnb0JpAU@JgN7jdg6uoZpInl82WqA22bH49Z6wYiC8jMlbOAjA1fS2NhXs7NcrhxULP71@jB@09KJjMbt6LIqbWbTLiGZWJs7JwnKlHxCJiNQ3KAZYpCArQdK1o@@QC@kL@6oa/zQ8N@gYNVcXQbiQuYniEVDHwVfmkYssrEP7hpGHoNJYZkcIzARyA8mBHdfQNjI38ZdICv5njnjBCf@787PKTKYTtYkkcjuClWY32VoO4CUFGNAo3T2bgmr1zBnzz17QyakHRuA6coD9PpjylVaDfTwdQbo@PY4M2sUGzi1BZqBkPESVy1LAJXxTy7MUGrOG8hpocNmvuDzq5ROzpDw0Zj1zALw9kUwDR7ujqi0WmmPGSpP5ZTsuUpstWuHGofgRWq@Ikv1L2eSeLRDQG7ps2j1jloifxZOVFpSP4fGzT0/jSXFVXyLb4L6x7N5VI@Eh@kX1Zk6iT/zRGVjgXsUtyuXrXALCrgLmxiqDb@6Vy/LQE@gbqjWU3J9P3MfgBDEi0R/pY5aY2tzQp8zIm2gm7DRZQJTq3IiwzVIpUqjgQREyo5x9cvH5O6Hbc5ZQaviZXQj17B4@3ppj1lBluQVuKiTJNvFbmHsgcaHp26QASjBkqRDYGnYhUDMAIz5IZN7BIQ/GQ1p4kLnUFdH0aUDa7HOQJlRrVr/LIt82XZYcxXK54jfoMlcsM@h919mhrADYa3wukOuBur4NMKAZqL@yEFsw8uscL0blxjgij3zjYYBOLGL4O7ApxgDWwix3d@jiL7Fvw1gB@aBSeXH8sF1KKiILjZANXLOHm9H88xmhiud/8AyGqbKUNF7lGt1HmA3Nvba5lTO0OvqQBox4haXGomTwTWYHyrK36JuqemOv9zP6rQApczgB@C9rtwNwaKI3WNRZEbea2f/sZzEUNhKbqnrSdk9T8XymCje1mmd5dmezKUmbjUzt3qYOWtTkzawJOrmylXtwagz7vYOB0hRFlmU5Rdk6Pz@PP9x6Zr7Ms4LUM7XCm9n8MlvIvpldZtXSm5OxWmjIb2YtsVRLn7TYs2efvWu/S4qz0/kbsZnQYnuHF6KaQ5U/Vimz851CNnZSBvUTymXshL2F66TP8J/cb3sRt47uTh9U2LjIYs0mUFwVi6KiNOIt@Cd1/xVcXPFv1OW6vNN69y7Z0PXJbM5M0xx7vR78nCFIkFryOQN9@S5wep5BYU16kgaF12jWv76ekGdstmsMBtN9va7he/zyvXZ1bk4fTp58/mlwvcDr7VEk21v/49upVEKSGivWKSptPR/Dz3j/2U82LtPnz9rbf/bNkWJs4OMQH9@5fILu52r@zsbGnfv3c7m0pmnc/ezzZ7@4u7ube5DOP2vkd3JSZmP7T/9kY0PTtjVlo@V5aiveODn5TNQyOVH@sx/F28@efd3z6tn/8xvv6ireinA7ZUXgE3BlmQpOvJfgp6KM9aFX7G0Merkam9NfOxaEn28wtb5T/C/fO3wTm8TqmvKpC89J7E2sUIpxJzjAlw18p7F6bBuTFS5jc6VWq4Gz@F/@LeSvfwxwMGa@Dbd6PoBVmMfqUo2yXMTqBXComgbl/t/f@EYEQ84maiTGBdc91oBLzBU1cacF1xZd2wIad5UyihKksyfDieEwtXRXvYseEzzwsA38SoYxacbUUo6xw3uMHTVSqVRLbktwyS9pkUhRVa2pqneBHUh3tmo1aYtx87XZbP4umuBP0pLWwIEZ07j76T/EFVsVWP25wR0JscLGvVcP6nWoU7ae3aqn6PIHEo2pYkl0nHsiS7NXcVBBGq1Xjxm3uV0XMyVNTKfT99rknyGtpFnYk/Di91gsDMEhy66GLWWBJH5o7Muni@3j9ef/259//8@/R3/fp99/QOu3ds/sK1uQ6BSGRB2ue5VKt14X66543kR/HfpRplKqlJT2ZTOxBRyodcTUzEcX8Xw2/hy5P13NJIwpSk/F1v3i0V@PLYLrPKQeDfMjeGIKgKdPKRZbphq5Q6oxdiUdTK3@ewJS47TeklAgqkkNtZBvSTxXPbjKrHEPmknUimWxVdfy2iG7157xiw03PebEQDMsBHT08a0v6lYPYxa@ejQoVg@y1Rdpvmy6EF8h1mgoLYMmhCCM3duobJQqhYqmtOvrL@iaUS8lNQzjmRc7jYUXp2xsQdBY2DWvhgVNEXpY0IPZl0kHjbVisVu7cjFqpWxBFau@S2szsQo9RMtK2qAtZlQxHG24vg/XBvzRP1yhF@8bFOIHU5Lr1warqFtaVsnfKexrOL/eckWRF2CeYN1Op/O22wGpQ9c7eldXJ/pUn@lzfdKZdmadSXfahWHDM0Bf4/9u1sk7JSfwylIsm1c3Y3dh1sHE2XI2W8xlC4VsoZwt5rPFYraY0Ur5rFbOFnLZspYtQIiWLRa0EoSUskU1W8KpIFsqa6VctpgVYu8aG@yI87IWSwVXM3Xr9UKW276THA7@JMmZxYTYP8BVVzWVbcEsl4EbiHbkBM0b/1RVYDEQ185b77Ya77ZgmNdT28RiW3XJxxIecvteKyVdXjbAXa36/9v10Fmli7ugcq3LVGr7ZR1kmJf1RgpAvvRByhIjoHK73tqmmLAwvzQ/ersFUpCU2m5s15w9@sk0zKR4zokXnHstALy9hOy9eykZXPcAQH0TRnUyldqUpA2cYRv@jAOJW/VUUCvEIQEyx/n5z/kDdRF4weX2Zf2ysX15ub0N/9t0v/SfEHq5fe2fHotrTZpFfAsZVLOh1JtK02c5LfDLSh1DZKUJjjo8IV0jq5VaDXTAJbf@2/yX04t7GIIot2TAWohtsa0YWnTNxraE2Kv3X/wv@Gu@/@L3Uepk8GdUhNg5MgdlC3XWMldd4cbsJzZ7wi8b3PgLvBiCAU/qGGjzm43bWorySmYVvnOQUEuFpIzTeNvpt9FIjMxeQdIllop8k4laqSC2U@pcY7FtsVAkpvkL1654PP6PXmnlYpwv96CVk1ee5z2JYLnAExJXtYwqqRd1/iEP/s2lX1h1/aNfWHcJsYsyMypAnwTjhBFi0I9iiiJJMO3Vt0f4GgxuuEio257WPpNe7Eq4GKNPaDutyxcaagf7tXK5zveKNp/RqNl6sAV3Ff73N6AarNmHtM1@rTsCMbrZz@a1Jn71ISZ13uDf47f4x467@Hf0Bv/Y8Vv8O5rgH3vSwb/jN/i328G/4xH@3X@Df0/e4t@LAf41v5LNqlVx85wok1LL6uXmTCQKVWGWqje/MnHnFfqEmajtaKA8@utViWyunIw1v2LMusZ4UvEXFvGlJKM7qeq1crVT0/yk/olqjJFNL/hGvL@OWNFYElc8s@W840p4/A9uEJDKllXHjf/0u9/8ZrxWi0tx@vpUDsKkDibqUCLwQs4cxwS/6gv4QXt7Xrx6L/6VBq0l5MutBka2IEKI1dimuqlmrEw3o3bUDjhMlnFZZpgZqj2VdK6MwTLzzJxlRo7aA5cBfxlwmZk@ywxYxs7YkAxiwTVpZybo6sNjAH99AOTCn4knyztqpsugIAtlT/rQrtrGnJmLdlNosDgTXxmgNMuqnJELZgu/DdYQX71qKlstrVxiMvZrud141Yy3xKaI34vQyjnWmRsbzVciyBgZkfd/DGExzwNNvBpTmk2FEx7IRS15edlu7z990G4rOBM2nziHi//Dw1HUe@P/6NB5cuiMHPg/PDyE0WvUU/dSMEfcu1eDOcN/7MTq1Z1mhWaeYPaJKds7zXpWQnchBROKhmGpL3ktIMKzvtEU4megCZ2BElVNgCp1Vj2tVs/I8Sn3gqONbgwM/898h/8kCNVQETuD65TAkg@dZ582Qxd3KJ@eQdCnDBTI8B801aj3v8K/@d/W/5MXLMkSjVYycX65naAriX/J5Pnl@aV/rycTCd@T2IY/DAA/Zjm/rKOTEp2Dq5FItpKXlzwM7onkNgdYh2K265R3kQ5mplhYJBXLb4n/uk8o2r@a8SoI8HyRIJ@hcRQTq0xfHBBqNmeZTBL4nP8pHNzu1i/oFEaySt9B3ew01Naf/og@d7STpET5XLWqbjHu0XJatZoLfMVStVoKPJuJRPn6Vc/sqAVQpHK5ZLJaBc9OADYDXsjbYO9SrMaacG/dvcsLKWkXFwHMbK6QyuDBrGo1KCkPxRqe3vWZ/vnBIX0pCFhNPoaf6OKsJJGh74zhRBAXK@Ldu4mega8v9HZ2k3fvauXMxUUYMh5DkLoU1G73TLfdxvDsxYXYFulATzkP/kzp4kLNlFNqPOm4iaf4EVQoKiGp7I5Wp1LLwOS1XBGifQTy29uFXL1eyEFIoRRP4uEAzuIB37gYr4qxc6qDWipyDihWMTh60AnGsodz7flljBqU5fLJBDDSJIihlzH8c5Hn8rkun08CZS5FnlItl3nSJMsVEqVU2f@rbSRZHeQs/ofCYjaV2ypu3QOxG/@82aoLeXL13Kipl7Vzo4LbA5fVrv9Fe7S2Y9y9my0DiUqZalNotx/sHu@22zWYy1BWgxsGEncX0AiRG69U71G7qqU8gwbkgVIcpgRWAior2lZeLSFVBLOP1rOABgLX8zbYhqDRE29CmZNqAwJBhYLSenCxHuuwAV5sgGonM5lFF7MYj6d7txsmcvjlx4ZeykuaaRBihJfgD7ss75Mwaz97vLu3f5zWtiUW0x7u7qW15y/ux1T05hd@is6i/2h/98HhC8jw7PH@7vP9jw4@2X/xDMI9dra4Ai7v3xfPqGuF/4x9Krx23@qGoRtTw2ifTadnb9hr02yb0HrWFCrlDFzmGW2oy1hf1KsKv67p6a9f6@6YLvb@h99@/8P/7v3vfPf973z7/e98/6dffP/b8Psx/L7Ln9/9N@U83n/6xT/73fe//TsQ@B/g90fw@8lPv/iNb/Af@f8Yfv8pEvbH/i@Sjv8EgPUrP/3iez/66Re/@gP4/Uv/94Prv1/7yerf97@1/of5vve7N6f57r@F3@9xWEHa7/42D8PntfS/zdP96g/e/4t/x///1P9D5@@8/xd/jDff809/8Kf/6f03/72mlf70X7//1vfef@ub77/1nfff@sfa@9/412omevvd99//g7/6w9/7qz/8H@n/x3T/vQ/5f/@Df/oX/@tf/O9/8Yf@7yfw@3fg@slf/HsYKn/7Bz/E/@/9wd/@0Q/x/3/@V3/7B7/@t7/yP5HjN7nj//mX/4bf//rX/uPf/NZ3/uon3/ibX//J3/zmH/zV//Gr/9dv/Me//u9//6//yTcx8Dd/8ld/9Ct/@c1v/@W3/vlffvOLNfdv33j/4gPCv/gHCPlwPD8EzofU68uGfPFz4fP3ocaiFOgn0Lt/@f1v/BJ08H/B2Ptv/xhfTIXfmv8fayql@TH3/X/AoV2vM8ZkwAW/X3//7e8iif4HIBH8h/T6TuhZiuGe7yw8QNbfWpHpl3/6xT//EfliRqVO@004WZe0UmoLFJqtctmfsP2tKMjyS8vQQgB@Sd9BDrUU9x3kbe9/@I33P/rH73/4m@9/@Cs4W0u5cno3Lam37ONBwvwHpMOEhQ9Jhwk/g/LbKVrWk1KfgW/js3wpa9t29bPPPhPaFwq@AX3vgn0Gf@yz4GI8Ct@Q9qOCOAzHV6YZhDdevWrh5m8kTFE5cEXjTz8Kz@ZDSZJ2J7WjqBqPMi6UTZ6LVSEgW8o2I6gr/f5WBf4Y3CqVrfO0tNMEoY@yXgpGUCXVh7qhMFVPZ7eyOiRUcjwdq9j3MrlUcUvXQQVOIdwUyTxbgQyWz7JZyi9yxmb@qvcME822yDmjZXC@Fg53AW/0X2SsxLKM2fy/KrAUrY7zPZrUwkkOP59fBHcKeSgmNQu330goZFwq2@IhtLNO5ebKDGswm6VmoG2DA0pIQdR9kPtrtRRmrHEUwcsrUy8xQiWVqkG9MTfPk26XEMTsPkGBnLXUEWtv1WY8Ywrh1QNypAQMOhJVTUyVag@gwNrsAUNYCJzAvnpVq5dqszqCe8epk5ql7hNOCKyWmtXfgb9GMCGfEHvwDlAp1VKpegkLxEry5km3eSPlqXJU9xRL@W0AT3xBYuceY3dEtSTybZUNJBhPjffUIjUmhOQQ30xt@dWh/8BJvy0i@AYV5ZfCePwOycQ7XEzGBABXkmRZZvDDEws77B5EzzioFBULjxSHkKIeQT0gDGC4EJUSUtS@KfJA@bHa1pe@EBhWZnNzU4jVxax4KBPpFIW5JxV6WwQPUKIeU2FioSxisEGvzgS4QP4qlb8Zx63IOOOA2Z0U/927t8XuQDXpuQgTmJTKOjknxqFsp1KiBvDrTkp4CfqPAP2UAF0I8qxGW58pIZ1mTK7FMI4dHh76SFDAy5qQgm6uZVX04wbcdDqNQQ5ZTsvptP@U6UkBsu@QKdZ/yptI3DPXnBhM03JVUNOqDINYVKdSQdfGwHfv3kGr0Im0ygFoucw/nKblShQJAdwAlWXNg3estFxZ4EsATC3kGEvQcjJcSYYvEyWgIyUF/iYDRyO4EnGtVIpTSqC/nNgKTisWVOQA/K0teh@Z5YtLXsAm6sVlQb74HKtjzYKLK6ulfDKI3Dtke4dPnuw/PR63WkzAr9FOJ0Z77Dpdw/MSGLf79AF/6UUrF5KxRgOpclzRkCMJ@5UMdtTUwYOjg@cVxqnkt1mC6lGlrWufLmVViI3Hn27H/MNdIn5S1BGf472yIEVCKwO3TMbqQqxroAqEZxJQNa@yqvDEG9x3ZiyRSYtiWi2gCprEHVjA4xedKUOD19w6FgxCfBVG3t4mCgj1cymy@4MBdXakCdwhqeRg2XIpcBS5Qy0WMAE/QMmyQv35/jGAPj5kqpaRhfpnbCYjatKlULdqlmEPJsNNPIkoNjNipPabjUwa/7RsFu5qrpBW88XWxoZ1LmFBTeoP53ik9BK85xJW@KtwMeGrAvsqBMEFZeA5UeavpR8cVv2TkmiEMsGPS4pqHkZwUsD9AA5OGEevKgyc5f00Ibbx@ecTVq/vP30gHTwUYsCIhiw4LCiZPXkoU4foTV2DYgeM9cxPTPyqrNwzvbGlz2FUAjVil5eXfYB08JBpdY28PEcP75ddCumA@3KmCzG7Uqm9U3NF4Wi3UnmX1TQBAoQtBU8jbkBXoUMdWwr/q3pQSDZbUoAJqqIIj2w2K1BHFyqGwOjgzrtMrSbx3prNqXRuR8APFemz2mIn3k87u7NIm83wtBgDEWwwcVkmiCvyON9XEMgHRMOjinjsXKj64z5z924WF2KyuUy44kI1ZpfQNpvZXBYpjq@CtWK5or/XJIpiKyZYxoT1auCONeHGFxU1NSYy9CE/ypYyQqwRawj/f738bbTtcT2bUbeVMTh1cOa2FR2cHXDmt5UOOE1wlrcVE5zTelbNbCvTusCEbW63mqFZrJo4MWZoJp@HiXXPsPoyvhlWE6kATdz2vwNRDzLWe7We053ioZxqTzZt23DRiAXPkMuJVcdGi6q1YPMK2FjyXBjUzsjUhmDUBjIa6XJt3RJ6csfpzWVvMrfwHSvLcWtxEH3jQcQCugEyES747WSzuUqDteSxM94RtHwx1VAzMJnhTy2ltfSGsVMsVnpy1zJ0dydfyZfSPXx9y99b3MlnKgP5syePH00m4yOD3unayZUhA5q1RAN0O6VKPt9qNEQx1aBiWo1MS@b8TNrYACZg6D0Jnrjz6ElaqQWZe6Zbq8XjO1lVk9RKNlO6FBaEQ5pjDesCZk1hzdJI93OfZVRsxwbuVEnrafOcqFDp9/uXW@ephUfQzyXuA/pcSnq6cx56q1IkXYVN05K5iIQQvQ/kPvc3VSuili@J1UZ14S8WxGrrUrg3Mnqmjq9yNTPn13MVgItzqDEoqMmEy4rrOJNKx@g7rrFImFULQUKO0PUEOfEyLK6ZwRLPrxdXiCSanV@HksuLl2GuAC3h8hLozokNZPeNktfpyHNDLeda@8CzoPtsB/bKMVns5UshtnX0SbZeh6Y@zxW1XD6X17KFQr6owQRVzhVAAcyomUImr2kAJVculYuX0K8V5V2MPkfK9s6D/l6hD7Ik9Aq3KNxoseS7p6Z1XspKHI9Esnp5GXsnxO4cfaLBjLr2SsB8/okm1WvZfBlcWXRpWUCYCZomaVkpq0pqFv9vcWj4/@HpNfjX8A65sppwjGbGnsI8C1KEzR6juaKJw44d/GDdgN03umtS7A11Oo@@5zqe9/dIc1@3T3jUA5Pb9g6jHun41U5vZE6Ga1K8GI/QQpnh/oNB2B91AEFkhzzBfbi5luOsSlBkL56tqeWT8GsaQAz@OQ1IfnTw0aPjyPN4f3fvkVBg9w@fPrjyyPuJ8uzx/sPj0FvksUHWfAjiF/cfP77q9R@5wxdH/anj4k94ePgit7iFQfi6s5CDazlRGExA/Bt6SWYFEQSUwnwxcKgCviRzFxT1u74zX1g4M@j8lL/LbXrhSxv8tf6KcBy84K0z5LQdg3W5ITpcOSAjsb5WoRbLgjBmtnPGihnWcyxLd5nT729A4FDHl1UNlJUtC3siFn3muFbvzOwZG8ITfC@2DCpHn5AQHgGQ0bRLNk5A@kGT4zCr2Qz34jrW1GDTMVsbCA8MQqdrDoYwB585QQKho@sMfl/2gvxG9JrcHDDhZVDYtRjrenIB9MtSXhT3RPGRPtGrrlF8malUnrm6NzD2Z9BX2QsYO7o7T5fSWXEiPmRyO/ZySxvgxo7ljFGz8cYNEPBBNdtp/vVv/fjv/uTXBzVgMc3MXiaPi1LbO08e55y5XrG59KdU3/kc8CXLV4DbgSTMSNj1BWKZlCitXMqXylmtlC6VS7m8Wsjn06qWBoW1WAbFIqOW1EIpX1bTpVwZBJNcGWLzoM1wcVoJ5GdlqwJg7a417RnbpIfJQ1C4@HYse5vQkyymh/4pEw3IIwqoI0/IFsCWWYM5lakZli0ygKizLos9fLiXefhQFO@jB4@z7GVEsYeefCmTKd4XRYNi9kooZIkOz1NC267ihHsymftA9SkHgJ9FEcUhevYLuMooiiZ69nYfPsRy@ujRMD8kO@Ex3GMFniIks9EDUj4BeBNCg2S7vJwcIbqPHiwSYx7ymD2IE8WPAnQw5ogn4wAeBTXd3RXFA@7Z3cWYPap2niP6NfTs0iWKLnhgNIjiABwDF8ahKHbAiWNCFLvg6s51CBuBC7@cYU90UZxz8iCBRHFGqfXuiSi2g3As5hMfmzxSt0Ieldf6HnnK@CeKWoA0JsuGnqwo5kJPDur26NEn@nDSMwb8mrv82YWaPnqU1c3ZdP9h56OPOoNBx53v7n90hFF7e49AQJlP3c6g42fstOFyINfeI00/Gc2vXlDrg3a7olsro77Wbud0@0pUe942EEPI9QYw868BFjRq70HU3qP2PX3VdjoBbCM7GMGzg9f9ETzv6x0eFVwURc9ZpyNWsfsrSjMhoAqB@@I4HE@Avdrpkd51nSr6ZzWWSeMYnjcKmVaVItgIVIFM9RLj@wm867g0lTyfN2a1TKs2qxX9g3D9hNicaXlTTG@MdtRyvrKh76haLjWroDkSpx9ncUndYQn17tZblnia3NFALRCbOzuS2FBbO5paqhSKL7emopis4H0nW6y8TWTiGcbwlmwUWzvFfCRHsZjSFa1SLIJwBjSZwBzfwQWgdiJxZugnySRiS4sMUAWqK5tTPc1qPzFLz2ocLzZPVmc1tcotxrPMNWA9/DzJtDtxXA5yAOBmO5kKnsFIiGq5JAICipJIJkOmBzq/sFiv@fTrxyfHx5@RFFj31z@euQZyr6rv/ejRnnxwGPjwwyLyQxROHVfeQ661FMOl1CDoGNQS@RHMq6DiBWH42qfrWPI@nV8ECTeICGybyb6Rb/n40RKc50PnjJeMVjOqZCnW7hoMv7ti9pheq4NL77EEYcX05BnN6O16vdaujciwBFQxyPU1Rh8lWYA58DjuoS0Pyn6Or0L6Ee1a5rLaqc1iM4DTrjFJfTVyeq@0VLfaw8@t3K/dx8zVNjw7VaNmuK7jiqBgi9X@jl2b2p7eN54ZLlqpOTjcBPkC349M9JmR3GTNfUy9h8rLpVR3mb3A7Ol0lNCleie5HISrgGEAEifx9aDS5/TKbrsmipfVfo0lXkLSN@B3N1miJ99P7uSqQKf7rJ2EoMyr/qs@01ghVyXlI4GwYCgRfbDeOkvW6l@DB4d9UqkANn5DnwBULAwAmz2KgNRj87LarVksIbEZSxKRctVBrYHZL/C2LYliS5IaFy2hLkmfCnUYr9V5TK950w59qYtlOqqWKVRnEKYWc9UhNK/@clZ1a@Opa1Qt8PpLgvztZL0KRAXaAZi3F4n3v/SN5LaUr/GwKoG6QGGgLbdrs6qNtn@hY9SyNYhINXKZNKj1cCumYc7XCmm1kM6mc2mpiKEw4afzaQgEtQfEjoSVEBkT05lZRlbTqqGmE5lXZu9VMn2SAEmGiMaS6Ymzb09HDEKgqbBvkheeQJ6UtmWBOtZzmL4tUWcFllHFigHVh2xspocI6sjQLcqRTEosu5WwNhOYZvN4Ot5vtCqV/dn46xCVkN7sFFLFTOptMllNbCRrnvFGqFeFOrIXqvV4A3quv1rKvOmoAa0MLrWoVRqNDlaxmElnM1mondm@GGyLdbGVzmwUVGiiS0Zsg3G@EV1ARIlnETZuozhuGdB0almrCjKt5mVLmlRW8lv5DF9R5DmFsc/ekJIs0RSDN/ET8XhRi8eT8Spuk2yI/jI38DTiZ3HgrvG76o4IwphYEcsaJliwRnrZOhNgB@LYpYCyIsuBtnsuXJ5fbteFrwjP8RXabe0l/hVfPtk9xL@vQFAZvKWXT14cvjh8KDCFjryC7FndqMrVdhU8kly/J8QqjAEnbfpmwpQNxr7sYdrUdv0lfzbxRQ6AK5A9/wZr0SE3w0RVjn2CJih2WBzqoLujhqZlWw2tCHMfcNMgqaapVcCiHcNXReQ6NMbsHPDbTtXx7c2vsflcT0mB/n@3Uh@kNjPaPHbaFgvlLH8Lsa5mTthGvLjFQJyRWOz0ZKNe2ErFn1WyqfiDeDYXO000N@v4YkB5ayulzePSVgq3fJXeVqpfSt3JbsVfpCqlQbqipvCuwb0SZ9JG7F47fS9Z9gRqEBa7shyxW9sdHO0GJwN39@olbe6/cxp72RZLRR/B5iYQTEu9XM5dh6n3JS65NwV8yyAeO4@zWPwS/oTYPXqvVePvtbJY@GYr7pT7@0fZXIElY@Wk7yuWY14i3Lz5SvxeLI57JBXPexejDhW8Nvi1Vxr05ZjtBAGg3@HaG8y1@TxuD8SUV2Pvc62UfXJwaD9wHxpCrLlxseHgtg5bHIN8Z3/8dcbGQN44a9Zis1rOP7Gv1uuSuq2hJb8iq8B00lcLUuaizgdMnSIKGsS8/6Uf5GbboAMxLaOCX9PyKa1eV7c0qNj4/Re/jzaZzvc/2X3M4rjE/3d/8iOt@Hd/8q/oYF/8kpb9tWwxBinRqRaKsfPz8fn5JVw8Lh9rxa6dZ2gBfRRVLxe3ZKiNUtLB0VZinI4gQBXVZMyTYv7pzUJeSiRURUtuZUuZJMRc@DbXElqmBN5gj4yCxEJeTMb2j8y8pt7b3oGa7WRzWnUD2lIN31Fm4d@24ZVRm3zy6oIx8HTrvcHA1MilKKzyTtp@x6Rt9g63p95JG@xVrY7nMVR8sznYlNnCNz1xzzNeTylbcQaKF6s3LquXrRTt6pDW@nLLbl6hQ3MDX9JZDtqy4c/Y8ujPMMhLAR54A5@x9doTE1tJRen1xOtrdNsGy9ehq2wpi/ev2VawV8P/JKmZfP9Lv6Fphb/7k1@7aF@0P9NAeS2XC6oW@9nPtqf21DN69Z8BgBss8QQKKMmgaDIHHaHiyridYdPPFTrkLujMUxuFdJ4@UGNRcWUg4JgD2@iRGiucolBGLdvmxiB7CUq2hYY60iTkk/G1ZFUQAmmYC/HuoJsmGGwLjWM3WknhXPgqRsGcz0ARqApfXYCCgBHM8k637VlTd0wvOSUon9pKs7uQBUr4Khra3CADI/6EIQHnVLauZ@Uoe0Q1EuDYyPA8NNsJc53wVcjif0HAmrOxjrZwMKVpwwwlYxLCkyJ6DSi7BWVbPEObQhNUe54gzTh2PJMNgr7wVZBZiAomiDLM3IYEVWArXwUCQB0SPmCzxbZZNsnOzVSqurAJeonvQuA7P3pgh0PAbAith3ZfgsxVTAdBoGDgN6uxX/gtDJJkJDAAwmHwEw01UFEwO/lQOiRDOR8MCmCRUboEVY3dvbvAqlYze0lGNUL4J@YY19yoHezVuAKwQL2706uIaYbWVqtBaNjtgOIpQhd6ncTNrFYjWZmI3ktBgP8P7rTYI680FUVUsQJ@e/FR0QWSQWYkO2/DLtuuMVUrJlmIfBdw7xJSZA0h1Fmbszuy9lkQeQkY/iwWfBEOmNZxdB3T77dXDbEwkOin@DkuNMfHmYFvQIUb3EPmdzAJcoe5oCqmRan7pgvaFB21CGx9JrJqErMtbKMSHvS2gpZj@NJAPokPyoWpGTx1tFnpl7NBtra6DjSoN3ZsMnJJRrjwjQ3oEcCjfPuAHO2pfYafb/TbhjJHMfLINiD2fMSYjHY6aM2I8uLRhY4LWndAmzQzBjLrjnpMK7MEdTSyY2iH4JKUiRDugFCONO5YxghQem4Y9KqhV1GUAQhq0w4Zc3xiQr8aPjRhBrI95QEnsHJmnpjKMdpRl5w@vpHITePEULbD4cfPPviGEy3HOWGWeWLw5enEkmEhj4FaApJ1Gii7@AFhK3heR8umcXVETfNU8CvCo8idpXQk70Zinrz@zKobiTa26AXNNya0imWc6naEvnRdCL4@7s29wDQZGdgCvxyyXMM3SlSLo7mR0NqW4BtZq5F9Lxm3PcYJMSYGxsnQKYxd45ShZi3gHANMsxuY@cFRDLX9Kk0ANPZgZKHN0olbQeNUgInbS3Rh6PkM3mZ3WFYTMCG3HOdbeQMY2PS1ZegQB1mxHt6kBw0j01o/8hUYnaMexKFZFL/7Yf6gd6Ob7Mkuujfb8MHhpENl1RgfFoEnH/Hg6MD@TFXfgMgCYLgCk42EmAKwKTEpctBh/qvZeW8XiJdU2HVIaYYQfFIDFBIVdGQ5aJQy8p1FASLu6x7/GI9v0fTs7EwmM7tT15QND7896Dm2binjgQkSsaNMjNHY/8q72VXGAdyFS@KfHJXHw/HODOXaWvnunD8Foe/V/ENMiXjfi@PkeIqf1huMyCQf2sLzqEM9NOmznN2Ef6aK9z@tlT4P@l8F@59Uil8iEMYQzCw9T3fTACzd6Z6k@2e9qh9xSgMSgEMrGkEgGr92A8/IC1zmuB@mcCbIR8OojnVCm8cASeTLyIuieQ2DlPPA6/vH5gwy2cYZ23VdfZ6g@CSmxg6cmJPYw@Yw7VMMOPFDBefcErM5a8xbS9lnYXaY1MKjEy7a2xPObwbKzXJj/IzHzyB@xuNni0KDYhuzFhfJMOgSq4O9Hs20BikRzDxIc8lNWC9iCDLI40zlIDDlfCnsEn7dGuUO6M190I61oGNAnxgDwY2E0njZbDRbtmecbbVSygA6u0iEgBYH0I0W0fSsF7qR@tapNXa8pSAbrfPCrOTjjUHdod8beF/BOoYNRB2D08tEg6qDkX/GgwsEfoUBAsphEImiwe4kYSaroR14ioSO0xAXNOaINXxkWiR9@VF@GIhLnPScsFFArQggDA@rBGhCDAtGDv/SbMAdPnUdSBOklejjmCM07BdvxYGSV4YK5zVVaqQIVpIUoAlkR3G1drUqQTw0ReNKVKSal377R9Hf@NLo92FcrMaeOiyfMKpCdKjgiU0QIfzhQlRl9VqkXQEDZUu3DBdmrn0un/qzNRSzpQRqBi8Hq@CdmZPuMBFp/G6Stw@9sSraYiXsCvNaDao4r/FhycdFQFJO8DCb52ebBx3Bz88ZCMDIrMxm@Nlm0WyzWo0zDjZbk@0sguSMkJzxLDz1bA2SLT8baE8HwfSCzdMC6RSPlIoAT@XTKIhBY5F5@qmBO/Gv0egobl34ZS54DvUCvw@hiI39rNtaWXojgnSEaV0BgB3xGoAe/2h9RbjK8FQp9IU8ipMy4FHc53cDziuggxELrnLD3Imwk5EODAK/mKJ5AMaumGoIokrLz/iX4T8xHQQGP/V6YGY5pbocmElf@fsHCWwhZSMDNCJ9qJkcMmTUZF78v9193XbbuLLmtfUUiOy0yIT6c2InkSN3ZFtOtDuxc2wn2RnHraYlymZHfy3KP@oke51zLuYFZu7nEeZVzjucq3mKPfVVASQoybLTvWf2rMnqtkgCKBQKhUIBKFT1tUdbW@dYVrULWuCQVnd6NVDOHGWbvhcvdNHiaXdwWuz5sKhBKGv5WhhOXLN@wAGOejEcjP3x4PHjiiyaQma7efXLmiE86w8QAc9yzk@6XnsQRP3cmDq1NTjrh1HgKfhN/RzoZUegw4VkbD1ZPw6iTEbbdskyFqCFr6DqNpthPxw3mw5MJt1KbFrOFpRgz1wug/UvPVnlSTxpoPtDZ3D6a9Aau7fDRKQJXewobH129oc6EW46aopkWIv0f0o9Jw1GRYNk5che7KFKn44djrtyPugNzkjru4gK2IfNTIFvJLCBkD8cMi6e8rGkrVjxRniUOC3Pd3XRn767qPpp1fHduPxqGkCKGJ4aTdMYlB3Nqa55Y3VSzNR3@P34Htr4Hi7Gl1fh0zjL0rwqid9X9SMngUAZEzQe3Y4Gmk5yqz2DTgqV@DP0KilwZxTbbLHWBqY1ylrT2Qsd4g8vfovoLUb8/U30X9yBpnj9rt3n07BXhxOSNz0Yf4qLncicwzqUveFC9sxWF7P2zh3roryIF70LFYLUWBZcfTjgpoGJCFNRvIFsAN/C8zASm@F7thyrSuIcnEaXnvq8enMX7TTbQdefBG1H5/QsuKbFB7RgY3l1t4ZD0LHQG8haz6G5y41TaRoH0SVT5QaW8b1L172ZrSRLGHMP75Qzho2b6Yf0GdGMLb6q7FbTOiCXW8Z27GWI7U9E1pIYD12JWKnlqMw/0pPwunE7QYgOMnuWvaRad5H4PHDiJt1hRojzFtJNhgt2AxEOtWb78PtIdHtLqXOtQlXTy5l0dKP5PR4u6nGLKwxPyrHT3VjyNqa7M89ZrCbAEhG2/X1TyAxkGI@0Wo4NUb4s7LFBf0Ym4Bvv0/VvmFWacwRqXJIl3Tjk5TbrF24GK@MG/WLD6T39AuBZMG4KQ5m2YU9LB4FWnNLzh5bWor@Qkk5QLCoKyTUaVq6MeabsX77FdbZurLM1U2crVWc8AtJVWpkyrVSVuhfQPYu6oBt0xjdIZyRh7Uw/i8Q2/esP/BF2K77kwlwl9FTuMlchgZwLcpW6Q0I5185VdvghylUO@eFzrvITPSRjK/c1VzHDAhlG9MoPL/Bdi3C8t3KVbcf9lhn7n4PI1FvIVeI@pTw/yitThEiBdpPWiCO2/kA3czwKaGJjpdJT4JjIw/KJ92E8/r9E/0m8Mo5khETscT7gzOqhKqcmDWvGkHpo2jCRMuaM5Iqezev7u2x8FWdBNQ9pjWeXYfCkhi/n0sJIEEMqn2jQLyEIuVmZj5GyZrI7oqNrJw7lTk7XL5EdWR9oO5x@TJlPkko4SJ0ub/orDUI68G54ovBNeM6gY6pjjHAm685BC0T9JbegUejrNC669@0e4r3udCbCNm@ySC8xWEumkw7Hh3McG3MwTDMJp8LuP7TL8KacDEpw71Qxlgp6ZN6QzJ91yyAY7MHvLmqOVQ6opUQQEo9LJzLK4nmBZTGSEllnaaoy@AgFS@bQCA9anzkA4I5@5HwibjyeK26ahkxZqZIlV1pMUuECvIhd@GOpPV681uFb7PuWr6bkNfZaHACwSsa1iHwdfIf@PhD93SjUhghTFcxTrOdPpbPq9cJZdgrzblLtbAci0VM77lzlKK4hITmtDizNfBGvzaj4MPkQJV8qjaFPafuGbPGa4Ba6Ta8tBBa0hNFl@uPnVfr4efVmQs1qJN3LglFaCqhJw5GGx5gmTVuMqzR8Xhcjhfe3/e53d/Ao3cF25wEeN2A0RXIZ5aOLPlu5JGObxLZ8gUgtV5QIcj4ujbs5@Ujino9u42Nb@rDfPNjZ33v9kSbdJ0@euHqOniT4YdRirzWexwUyW3LH88GcZcuqhyhdOOzGdnx0PhiN733qZ2dkiQhrUgZ8qsWwnx7jrpZlljyfGrtUTvJaFNWwPifDwE9JJag6PqbsUNN1TAQJxs4DXwMx6i3R2@PVmsvxqJrNvt8Lmk2evkwAez2LoWvMibj79@V7xYtoxIHaJZjaVSbDXjbUzr768Kp2pI5e1dXuu@2f1Mf9d@pDbe8IXhDevtt63dhW9H9977CuMilTPASexIKS6LoTtAKEE1arpdJjxZC3B8OJyB1n25Xvh35PvRq0AhxTPY/83otzeSn0g/GmlKrTcnSCPcyQA432wjHsLTgyJi1jody0@a4irh4oyntKa9oe1ry9QTvshJQ3g7XvMAwic71NdUPqQZK35oa3J0oSgmCy6RAHt4UF1hUV9yk/zm4IjC/2VyAxckjUzHZBacLF/76bgkf1gzeHCq43tvf3dhpHjf29Q7W7f0Cvbz829l4SPRuHRweNrXdI4oxv9ncau43tGn8QBEoFBZ8Yv15E44UoFJCdqdL6jJPvwpC6P35L73pDg1dXPt/ajFTuog/pE/rd8PegndvIXERQX3BTlI8KlLNSO3j5nuZ8FfyGE05zFMz2B9l3EQdmXSmp51wbDZZNGm8berjStJcvu3we0ZsoxGYKNtgDhsPPnjLA2YinHQYquw0bFex9i6MMHssGNFV0j2ADlDFYqSqOqZbLec8Z5CbV1uoO4JlVahMjQv2Coi@MqclGhimmbWUAFJcrGn3sB5U34g/E9/RhVVc7HkkG9Sj@IBnUY/kAVbQB2xG1pnNcjPcvIJ7Vunz4tTfc5WNh9ST@sOXzKvapxkn6jbvUV3FMSrgN6XLkPNnl4ei@4i8GRSLOj6hy3a4MjEDimZJMlKNEtm2jnFkSNh0cNWizN4kTjlTiBtgJ@Z1xpJyqW1BHMA4K@qHELDzr@n0xgUpMd5j31FM4f6rqS@FhHOuPr6sMB8yAiDOaxiMut6O1wuCu5ajk1kyNvraR5Hi7xgTtNgS2ZhD4I2AIUD610mnxTMUXaQFm0NGs7EQD4kjs2/7Nzk/s3L5oBakC2mrL@TX8/XdXE9lLrZOMnSJjR130ezAitZKPMjuDEY1xFqscHQ1SsHU@GI5D6UMn3QI@ceJpjnJjYqPafqlupmoDHaZr7A/6VqWnxMU31HpKTHmXWpnj5ew8Fl9J2GzifJqExe4O6Ping8vAOjvzcIh0FWD7hRRhPivH5udkzJiI/plJZMffFKLtPq1u7mx9yv/tFw8hd0UsSMRrY3SI/4kxURcNDz7nY4PFEfQuPdJMqMTo4hSltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPQ1rXvWhuxGlibjz7HVd5pr/zx69fq1IqD8mkw6RH504i3Tx1bKr0uMyJ0iYgluwkZEnWO@aLxzBjef0C13fQC3A51Iccwbp9KhChFiGmdacXHZIsOh607u4Yvqs22aLCKJLiLcLuj@LPzlb14aZbTAxKlEVOx4hoz0Auu65llsLz1Qy4ncXgSH7fHdzThdjJ9PBd0HYWQvsu3PIPb4Yl05IF6@5g/7YArExufwgstd27GbBMkrPQYk6PmdNbWY6taRfX@MtM3/HYIzCYe7GDEgO1arvo8xG18XPuSAHXBpMoRIdHO/WDA5WV9QmVJbmHJUNbi0HAvqfeJta2YZ@FXSFWmuLFcqw8mS8pizbzb9Fgnku8G0SF1kE8TY9YWCTe1DvhtUg9PbOwCsHW9ywQDeXS2H0xMig61oC/0RqQkE06zWpgZm4zl2XyCSPbCFzTzRPd2LbhZwtrmbsRZXk0sQHZNkH@GW6WzO@/D6IfV0w9omDB7RIa3CZNmuYbWiccUsVDylgopHtwQbeYLoWRvSjYy4Z2MPwqpTXsP89QzEiihIsubIl1rRxr1EQ/XjFqDhskYhrwYempE8WimRKMiOcvz@0OdZNJz0lPQaRkIu7uC5srqPjJNz2FMTXiebIaK@T2WFthbI4NlifYndWwN27OdB@20OvT4mG6KpK2C6vK/2OqklkiVZOh@dzGmESCvL629ug22NOtMMXzfxa2zCHT8nPcG9L6PgEZTSLe3ifObex5Jj1hgAWkE9N6M2CmCpKqM2dOSbWdJyMbP8JF9oUIGcQKQCjj6VpddT2F23zoMiPZ0DnLTBusIRw3VEbNDPW/La4OAvnW@u59f30y2JAJpoPfYJX/ZjCKguRWnuVPxvqEe/jpb8Fo1Odscp@pBygOX2NaeNmOb9uJwau0Col83ma3pKNvJ4nZrWf2GrgS3l4sIHo5dvc2prf38uUNu6m7jdd19YAdbXZSe5HZUda1ZM@9sL8IAZbBvC@B6YPv8N2PKvQ/4eAZkEQmvs3nMG3cW3FjipDWfMzRo7RZqJat5ene70Qtvw8PJF72fqSy3g9UkHdh6/u77ryd9dJGqjwhFw37DpXysvlClovSN2zoAlIahPQmvlsTFm5qGEtJXK85G8A@CgdbwbXsnrHlpF8sPy2tP8tw6/re2OsdPzvxHrSqWUWTr9/vRRejq/bns8H5ZUd11fDX0@vW5PfflFp7DEfbavUHcaRcXq8W2RXtEwUf3M9KzLkawR/ZKTSiaRckzLBSOZWswzfuKZcfeNFcwQ2JKS5VD3qGC3HFblztHa@fVPvV0kbvuH@ygUt@44fV8cPyQwcffqBZlGSMnMwfj08wp9q7rkH/UsGnKIez1VdDFF8NoS9v/FE4eF3be5najYMCgC0wbevNG@oSuXwJ1my4e1LoB1eO3ibzFDg2AwUps8S3gsq49M77ydiOaYeEGfWKR9psdM1/J25mqVS4GI4HnGIcQoK11Nfwa2bJXGMq8Y4CZTkOjdtI3C8gOEkeBwdD8nUiVtT5sqhrZdyddC0QxyjJ4jD7KZvFnUIgqu9yHZ9kokLgt86BRJfU6q9cTD1/rvBGrBYVeBcPphz@iC9MlE7wiAMQ@hnyaQOqYM094msfGWo@3st4kC@8RzXmezJsIJ9hTREpMP9WX/h@E5d/TgQQwi@JzlXQW5xa8yJFUu4O8uYCvK2lF/44ZsC1SumUJTQWsKW@agKcLcWZRqhWk4m@L12BnEIr@qdbkC/z20wz4vyuZGeS8Dm1fotAS@5STtrETzcp5ljF8qaYyWyRYulWamCni5ZHbwIaVhO1HXS7hLTQYikhBx75fq@u/2Fcf3SMOk9i5CU9P5OeT6UXJF2QSnIVaIJPMlXsTNnlL0m@byqbZPNm6qoqVl4K1NOtAqkkSd6NRXmjwnjQDJPMm3FXClfGCc9TCXkr5ec5vS8p91JlYgaP048lXfP3qu75GMtU3hfp@vGb0R0UsPGstjWZ4tJCP@z@mNFR3nUK2CxL1FRKinPcTWUGVVXfwdTihDQ47PPzsN2sJlAelo3E4TGT3Xz@IlvQSsaPzjQacotxZmDNGSMWlbjOh0y4a76wSPVw8j0LBMMEoykzcjdN4YkuPLHAItc9U63cgpwZ4NS06SFexb3Ir/hjBnsaOZNveX7ikmB@LY2X281pArHQvZedT6a0NMF1EfmoG7VgFknqnkxDnC8k9qxd4LjOQO5gd7ANfi@WE7agMJJihu5xiqZ0kqFs2PemLkTit8zfiw8yL33SsYfd4FrVsMzw@RZWJnXBfRxE4wg@qNg9TnQxHHZx6sgK3xVfodaxAVbXcNySQLRm9kKmAcseye/hSV9Ip0IFtQ/IVzAQSRKii7MzXCbDDdjBFUQrdlzCcSFT609kQ4PGzKNVuWYeKDjfYAHcDc9sJKTnZPSA0tHQbwWFDOloEWk/GWlqJ9Thank/HfdG4OqMprRKJvMvF2Hr8/ZLnOc@KZcelS2SXerj4FLh0ePkghURySSswlvhWvlxJmOdDbfkbDgPgJ56jYn@PfFmcBn0@0GmRjMGZ4xIaY2C0WXQLmQyB0F8CAy4YGWcTOIe9uBi1JLNHVK6fGJG3BKOPDkOIw7DL@ZnOS5u8VmZl8GhVXLaTF19GbZBQHPjpDPA6TAfWMBNgNADhXrBmIjywFVplPjsWePCuksPG1FEDfg5sc4mYjL0B@OwRT3DO1mZLoGSY5Cksn57ChOqr9X1cTm4MA8BXI9JKGAQMEdJi3DI6EPz78JB6YaZM3bf9EyRpN@AxwoN92AUkvRNCMy9wsUs3KmDj141DtXh/u7Rh9pBXdHz24P9942d@o7a@shn3DgoZ1fA6tX@a5Iu8Wm6nJrv04ds7ZBKZjkhU9v7qOp/fXtQPzxU@weq8ebt6wZBI/AHtb2jRv3QU4297dfvdvj0nSCovf0j9brxpnFE2Y72Pa7VFMsk5dT@rnpTP9h@Ra@1rcbrxtFHrnG3cbSHynCqX1NvawdHje13r2sH6u27g7f7h3WFhmV2Gofbr2uNN/WdAtVPdar6@/rekTp8VXv9eqqh@x/26geKjQSsVm7VCcvaFi1hURO3c6dxUN8@QoOSp20iHiH42lOHb@vbDTzU/1qn5tQOPnoa6GH9X95RJkpUO7U3tZfUuIxzC1WoX7bfHdThPgmUOHy3dXjUOHp3VFcv9/d3mNaH9YP3je364YbKvN4/ZIK9O6x7CoEsuWqCQdSidHreenfYYLo19o5oznj3FvYOLnXyByIMYVmjojtMYJhBoLVEpP2Dj4AKOnAHeOrDqzp9PwBNmVo1UAEWFdtHdjaqkIh4ZDdT7dVfvm68rO9t15G8DzAfGod1lzqscYgMDRhkfCTWoUrfcavRT4SXPBKzZgznetydqrGrajvvG8Bc5yYOOGxobmGybb/SNC/AL7C1iRIOsGfg9@yNlc7sp8sAnjBnd2Tm79HEHpO293fqNCNrZ1fZJOEdzTpPp1wp2Wk008SJ9JpyWdMOTi/OmmG/M8Ad07iYbHz0ojMPUZNcRJD5lFkQtEzvr3CB5eVm832tSQvdw2bT9e5SMoXGbSX0NviiXK5uI8JAYOWNjZ9KRej@PEWozR/0QScb6uEAAjmF@j@I6ZvfC1xVLLYDXQyX9wHYbB1FcmxyjqMUEo182RGhb5IqeWeC30PNDlzQMeALrSb2SWEZyZkGEf3pf01eZHKwPpB0lu2uYhGLWEYj/D0w1Ugl7BKB/2iPBGGHqyxEQfD5zCnZ1WHNXzgbDNqO65oynHdM68Azx72l@GlwNlU8P12ekeVjZx1BITLrblZh4vNnTTKl@6Uw4pY5@NMc849rsBGfD9g15ap4s1pvWjo/SHFYJHlKu7bA9QruZOh8b2p/bXzAaq60@nhj6vur@LuMLdgLwmcuTXjHXO6Ef16dSAYaYOyLg0gSag8ZxaJVxtibxJmvKOM5Ml2FbVj@0Fx9HvC8TiQhRfbC79p1YjYehdc29iSHXx7U3my9290l0QlsHz9de7K@kYndbv3Vk9@PqIfd2rLXsSHN46SncZI1SrZJ8eGRYnkVT9ifGbhYREa4kDedxh/h5yG220hbMkGQobkR4kD1YaKXDUCHrGIHHPcyhl/njkzNAE6qqS5a0/OvWcX3SVdiHtDGLN0J99o1/gB2PPzNEI8bpBlIsxg7@iXOpdUFy73srjEV5cUNO@5BlkLW8LG4cYtpwFtdbD@L27X8pnnb6sVITBkxXrnbuSQhcW8aC2XsKvoyst@ynxG9Aczew@jLXzW/0eNH7eCO3d350bg2PiQy7sYlsU@dbEbrRh9ryCcI6QGnaqam5wq7/K5Gisee3k6OHYNYo4FRQXwa2PimAW/EfkSmq2QL2Bc5V30RToXzDsDZ0Byr34lz5zVHQ9kw/kP0u/FKoQRW7OREqHYV15ExWT7GfiwMOVNk@lP0YPj/RJrMgf@cVpwEPaGW5QTwTpRkqEIrWr4yUcIrc9BgnW4k1LQ/fUzAfLM75jxumD69uZb7NUQC3TsT8@Ejuz3sOHMIACbHxoY9fmOTtHOflk4vsq4ujnOSfqs3dJSeK8xUMQM3v37isdrlmbMVvLjKlb0mq8LXVFS9kIXbKY96WjJNLeXV/Sgr4Fzj/6P4gDdA4gHPXHouVqvTnFXSo8zIAe1qyZpw2rHHJFJLv914avdAWS4yU7Jfn3wZQhHoTeAz206ObTJQYp6b9rjIM7E6Yi94cF6OZTImH@2y7pQNMbsB4Nxv82YIwp@MrzBBdAU6u@pLoCnnPhuKoJLE6jDxMwhx6xaItDytXsXY884kODTG/l1f/OYHsqtlchTEwYfG0L4uX1Bv/Amh3L1bs4XFig8OBx5sF1GZbEvo8gj10hoMRqQ6@mg34eiFE7egPuhNh6AfXYy0/0Kaz8KR3pEwSj9VA7VJVu88zYjDekYtCse4rdAuMH9wk3oBLETFPcl1fl05xLyGRzfNpmN4/bCsnOdJynOiCbslZSI@V@vq61fJJQTVLkMDpmAYxYsLttnkenDuEA@/q8HoM@Z@qED9dtCOPZNaIHkvUDqp0Wcfj62xNH04iHhHg7oCOyAxJcqykRYbqtIc/USzk7ZryibeMeG7lFvy/fXETGqspaiihHF17cR863nqTFBpVbsGjZ2FllfXGJV5C65vNy7G2Fto@thaZT/1Y5FSESWiet@ojngSuRk/fcST3uSv3o8weugLzri1CgqEobPiXHVWzjF@sCn4EAajtr0nSppM2x9i@42XPoM@86LZOtRu/1r@OAomtAJoFcPrIsNoOn8ZnPeb24OufxYOQp/WafA2fy0SD48TfkSHnY0GVxFHMZKQjFam9iR5Fv8y4oYN7/G55IblmisaB0PHNlMYjya1c3ETwTvnMAJMgrMyfw@nfaTFZR6vJYUy6funbI9XdjduLPuoPK@wnOgDgBZwm1MWFHKHdMwXk6zLpxszGU4XZbBwPFV55bs3WOylMH5GJOJjmBTGBpkZswS7EViZ3Yjxcfvaa7MPwhEcLQU7AcLvRA5/9nwEyCYp8iMsBSqq/LRkFZVTlGv4IcTD5GZyrz75J2NPCPwJ9MuP5nHLPEZgEdcx3pYiWa9oL6OEC5sHhiyjWRKTFAvPwr51/ZBjXVxPQ00nT26iBlv@kFKk3ezNcCVGpEMLHwTbc5okcpoTF5NKTuVc9tsBFaQ2dko3M2xwm/0sD34c4srOGQTTtobsWEjfRKoWUQlxgqfMa22Uxafy7SNmdfWuvTZFwOo8kzMrFLaTNZoL30AJZX7FsdZgRMI4O0U9beqRi8aDYe6O1LtRdsz1zDaP1i3XvdUQWJitSpPlgzaTtjrB42QjM43PFNOkKcaWZsRDWL7yc8zm00S8rjYx3qrNyS10uIlmid1UPKnE/d2WsY9J8RIWvWaiiYcU4w4npRvx9@MmNbx5swTRMGV51WSJ0YTIaE7k0QI1RaaYSnenEHOfxn2KHm2iHOptE@3s/rmRqNNGcsblqUlKObkEPeG4HZc2SS4NOzC@gJs40XBjIRUrnNfehI/yyvlTOBlGggCEVhzkk30o2cFNOmuKjzg6QMdpwlqoDElET5u2hUPs9D8mGHvl15s72uKhOcmXTzYE0nUMiVYVnGsRJHPfnF6Pm9cMZYYUNMTnkCJu0YxsOr97q/5sWygfQZDSnKwtfUseGuOqh4QN/bGTmtfQgZOqdMnUiEoPhCaLBhoLtEo56wayXIX2F46E42HdoIcRLSDks4Ofh7oE3Hmvl2Jqo8h1e4Isria3jDZX5TelSMJQ8g7y66Eoqi4vXAlAIBhT@WqZIMCtKWOPQwF2vWNzXgpR3UdUsFrGsKSP7BU1sfOckw6i6gyP16wcpXk5ntkw8nOBkGIxP0@CCOks87MkUGiim4uLlePJ/PYkOUghNrwvFKeu0L2SpmHcc0JAjnddchOJclxWXklzMCc@XnNTiTF/c@qzkpVamk4l@sQYHufL06lPS6nUVLWrq@miqZJED9euNZVIpHBthGOp8Of@8dUU2@V5bBNqLTJSWoa2z0Y8clpl0rqt8GuknvOlbKNjGHj2zXCz/GpKiJWUU/bFDthVjo8M4Lv9T7fWWKYaTHSsAPZLZy67OLIgZI01i6kezcJK13jaix0UmDXtoKPeH@3upty@nk6MoVEvGK2VSiUw8ant/N7YVmMrKRwU07mLnYtutzi8@svo/WmRZX8QcEiAillBB9QlNCiiwmB0JpEhgANlRe68vsiKtf5Fp2OHYMAJJTqPuk1yam8IiiegMDZ6eX/EG0AMUk@wv6CBaN8vKh59V74omhqKOYai0jAJvsya0zMiDz50YJ8dn1QxMAhmY81E85Zb3fyCGQSRTbiz2H2x@yUxT86@Crrdgac@IA4yPAUsfZsusLtrFyhJFpww8u3ei4j90XoquAy71r1iZLF5HeDMxGTiTBi/8PCNfxCc1a@HTvb45yxNK9Tkh2jmQ/in9lT2LOtqZ/F3ACt8SGjfKXfPHzotptN0Zprq9QhOngijR2Vv7tonlcXlPTFNs9tzg6jz0S2wswZqusu6gPFlz93LLbkhe0zc7Kfrcgc0LAkMjRN8rtytBK6a/fPE4uW407mbVOQwANKx3yURJRLKnxOIfAbAI1APP6InvGj/lKdhvTvlUEQUHATrmJU7KNBEgUzmfqv625VTq9XUyvDhQ1WrbdFDPq9qWzW1gw9bW2qH3rfw/kN1dW1tQ2TujvuFPm6Zj9/UFsHgHc6HrfPRDr1SWhX3xmCtjS5eKVZXvI2VZvX55kZUPK5t4Vo/Pf3nv/3X//z3/1as6Zf/gZctfjn@Oc5UKBSKK60vKz9828D78c5JbuX0eGV4kjvbAJf9nb2GDxrjvJ@YjxZGp5llmQWsr2xHatbZ7H1GF1Umpl/PH30m6VJRy62ouKy/RhI5imXsciuwvge4R3lKS3gTdGB6KU9ILBPQCbbjqXdaAQzwaL4hShIusAOV8nK2Yjbu4Q4mzhCfqixrTzyss14GuNOSeFLAXVyasfJhPwr62AG/ZJ1XmpfJ@PQbjpuaf4s/v4nOtgbX6sEnRz0oqQeeepDN8k95/Rl9dVeKIW7nSjZaDmSzHqUkRwswM1RRyIoerx841s4UuTOZFQ7ZA0jGTQVnlltwXrz648syEnAtOsssIeKnki0SPmRCkeUvK/1v1C1fKMe3bOqqDSsKTb2K4cqsE5W4f6EC@ZEYAiQ194QglQFViZM@vpGMp6L5ovs6w9GEGDDIevByl8c9PtBctNLXNs@ptRTCHLH5vHzF3Lghl6EZbaRI/QkCfKAiy8kS3yTMLecyYuVttZKbKbew7fZp5hNbh0kwNrbpUuhvymICsea2CbfS1/datCG3HK@obBgfr1hVZadtv1XGKtK76I7Dob6uwLVjQH2Ja/smIwk9yoAEjvjsr8yOMN4oMJ6iprpFgmVNVHuApstI6Our6dTBbkFOjiwiFH92aGx/nRrbbpFviRh2EB5gpGJTvo4fdiPtdWXExD7zR6eIDuh3OKDaWM7NeD8PkVunMB50YqQLDJlNzpPxTE1ZHo78s57vqeW9wdHInzRo2iLNZ9wquNRCuGACEhh8uup5zTMIS4t0lzBF4qaw5RCCF3QnOjya9G02vnOCLjVDQbtdwSBIsRNTMvia6qspOiZc/R2dYKM8I7zj00gtYlnywtJIQ8ra12Z4mM0MnYypwR478cDJZgTVeGQaXtCFLjDR9vjglyR5Fz4CdN1ZfQtQX0VYf4b6MTudBX0/NTkNuxlz0b@4oWRexHjmUJRijZTRUJ6Uk4h3wIr0yJ/TXiBkbjLujDJLjrP0KdLh3JbteYSdfMe2@EVfhXEAOg5gxjdD1Lt@KMJyaoZKYmAUVIMt/wlCp@ufEX6TK38CVvy07Px4r@ge//ypf/LA@dT/@ul3lzHRItnMsnm1rA@zjcTSY4VmxqKXejVWaZFxNfipn87wqa/kDotFAkKk6Bz/XDz5WiSEPi277oPip2UhSKrLgElxcX1FgC/OoLmcxqK4nFlyH7im850fy66iuZV/0YfywZVfwsIsKnmbntY5ow6B4nu6v13IlZOo@HS19Hi1/JhWQmfBdX4UXGC@zUcXp8E1qRIRlrM09Xz6PcUNKUJ8u478Dfp4Te2UsCZy9yTSl5S0CNXDnOvJxGxFZQrCE5SfqMzuUnHFxY3z@Dh8xILfU8RyJi/7ghLTQYv7HMyf0aCHevwIcm36dohwJKwMxEaEt1DzgGyCr9zEoa4ZLjm@51RQ2/DdykCoe4vL1mzRH/TzWllzC7kNKNG4NdN9Wnpamh6jM0M0NUJXtDKVu6fKmz8@@Y//vv/b8nh5c7X4YUS/4@XfltefLssjPdDbI/N2uby5/BzZ1r8tT4q0BqbHJ//xP6n85l8IDlImz@nP5pqBtT5Z3sxXucjX5c11eiivrlK9/@tf/5XasCIrNsRiXWl6ihHbMBTZ9vvMu5SuGmilLEtziVjhi1mAIRaGtDanFxhGXa8@LfE23bK2qrgMtOcrY4@ip3g2zBqzqZDsZBh7CtKMpEAVFeQFpDGh6CjLdsOYbYB5EzTVL/cL6xGtAH7R5hxxlbHpxv0IJkMrsiyiDnSkRlrPy8Nm6cdsbN5RyRqbkg2jQmJpp2Xt00cbxA5vB8E4bKWtJMxw7bX8q@C0AD4sBO0LWlP1o@7g11HxkliyV159Wuxgc7/IdtzFIUPKDyeF30kR1MGAaGHIRqeeGlEPDHpw4eVxtCBS6HfjMykTT5K07GHQkj2sdExiyiJ3/Dw5HkZzCokq7fBfUuAROVMHgrRipX3qU8n9g4rKPowzSj5e87rA5i0bx2oXGHmxhh2ybCpkuA3YHTTtKdRGZ3wJiUvB67pkKfjtdtPXaU5mKWtCpXmZpfOgO6xmO@LeHb5TcWKi6S9q5o1Q8iF2EPJ5FnSA1QvGPi3Rq1n@gvV4UgPcpOiz1thVXELWjs6rV/XtKkddWVD1lVR9RT0KLSGpJ@YZyxubsrOJbKliq3IUNHGkNrdiqi0yQZtHBf4BBpF0S6ODawm6OXwDkqiWNEdbldnd5vFamHjkKpA7e7K1KJGrM8vJ5UfP5JAb1NCdUG9BKiMBAS@4FVgo0/uh3IComjCjYT8j/vymko1/Dw2G27APV6K22zpxPirTUv8SsW/CMd@lVEQC7VfWtsHOyOwRg45dbMUhaLPYeMm6YKlOhRdbnNF0R4XDQBuXUNms7FMdt1QcXrajo9dKoAj6kC2VVx89Xlt/8vQZopwt6dbOB4NCBawChuc@wWCN2qFFNr5Xq9lcVj4hBPVslYA@DywO4GDWdeW6xu3zlXuvWi5pYKUsw7riMBpSXG9XMsgE4igoYEagNYozyjrOj5VjNOzkU9v9Sv8Tfxv/gMxwxh2tL6S3@uFt4pkq0xOHA1UWzOwUx3kEDyquTrHzBoPOAbxNBLB1Fbanil7DA8T4fDS4ODu3uaOgXVsd0YAhgrNfaqygXgbjxMGYhRV0Ub3h0LBuX1QNvOPZFsAoF1MCdD4BTsNM@630taUpRkeOJiF41sSNVRwhWqajNjszd/YHqr63M43Ysh2GjuEWbMtWUu7YkxkcyCBWr9XcI6Ku9nbBV0m1TPJSXpVZwJWQr8zX4X3clW4hELVFFSOrWW8YO4vIUmZeTFybJkWpH4HXHJjl0u2kNPdaTStAECMI9W5SLMS8@DzHJlmCk93JGKfg5WzFshF9E0YRO5jTlWVdbVHKmTiqwFLmBoDYtyllpSGlCnqUH@sceFl6G8Ec5VY0tga0GXK8Ug3m5uQwE2x1G4kDbEQdN7RA@xt7257aqdOf3Q87HhTlrdpPaHcc4vlmfMsa33JFNXZNF9jeYtnmFjZTv@GKEjFLSTuMTRCE8O1IVMQg8RpQb@xq2sugPk6N7ZOEK8CuvlbCze6oHiRw9MJ7IEt68R674uDrOvytIptXs5Imdqmih4VscS0e2BZNlpJaY0hCyjuAWJ0GETtqSbh9KWF4sUBnzdvXaxfD2I3d@TydYllZUJHavlsksqd59kbKLGKLVc0WqxX04yK@YL5dyBunQWeg76LFzHELb9z7Y7yRvztz5P@/YI76P4c7HmnueFSB7BHuiN2G841ODsM@mMMxpxOeg5vt8CzE/lDHekUjSp4FgAUeMMQdUkosl9C2G8SJcuYnPJyej2AktLqGiwF/qPGPdeMfVyBz@XEn@H@18fl/cOPXdOPXKphr5vS8Vu0sd@v/mBYnKqGT/jC3e6HuSjb3j7Z0Xbd0vYLZdE43/19vaf7/UEuf6JY@qcBjghw4iPv6xdwsmkjtcLvRSMwtChnttMtBHPv5XOli7dWuZmnx0OleROdVaOvqD@P/VOP/FNKInxCGDmcRsW1ovJaX5alclhfNknc5FC5ZSUukvcYzutVePWEl6xE9QYmQ5o2tkV6okELuSWJy2lRI9MdE@saTz11xFtmug2Xi4NxaQMuKsOwmQ1w0Xx0kc3U9nld22Aey2j46eP3wvwgZev5nfQuNkEfXXgXdrplJ7CXYUex1SjfGag5gH@o1R4pVNDkZ2bG@7R2zy9LNUo0dW0zNi/MXCXLUhvM/Wkv1oG9YUbmxZUS0KejyZlUF01yzvJAv1HbJNL/JusV/iEufaS59VlEHemFwE6l8veGneTFZp62urS2aA6RUAT8YgCWP8i8YVf8b)

Based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210373), see explanation there.

```
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
```

Answer (score 3):

## 403. [es](https://github.com/wryun/es-shell), 17020 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{ #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; x=echo 403;$x||echo 350;exit#;a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295# [']; print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68')));[exit];'"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';#wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;




















































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#8""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 ?\在ｕ2\0C05+---<?ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._#:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({3e5711d6-ce0f-4467-9ff1-59401152c5f5}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0kiwRAAHyzyOrq6urbfdUvdVffey2SzQZJkEQXCLABsors6uqQNLtay/bMejSyQ5Y9vrJmPCuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzkJgGAVWdVXtje8iyoC@Tx58mTmyXMyEwddwx/99KcJvNgT114MbXfKpqY/ZX3POjE9md1esFuG5Rc0XRAw1b43nI1NZ@pXhQRTGbMNZzgzhiYbWPbU9LLMN03WNW33FOI1xnZnzsw3@w3w6Yw55im77/SsPkBgU/fYdKw3pgdxecbumPbb8dsp67njseH0fTbxLGdKsQXGnhjgGcx6x8zo@lPP6E0t14GoImPPHdsYd/sGo@QTz@SZSgxA9Y4pz2pMmbGHruebUILbM33fxcAKBBqe5T7Yf/TRhfRqjn1kAFIT25xfKF5V2aeW6fUv5tDYJ0d3714M1dlXJNdhdy@jpObZ/mzq3p9ehF9g@0PTMZgmV2TtYmQRiDk17XKunLsYVYL2NKdWb6UciLhredC6RtCKrGc40FrYljvMHE@mCybx9jdsO2pbnxk@m/kzw6Z0zmzcNb0woT81vKnlDNmpNR2x6cjyo3yU2p8YPVPqm7Y1tqZmn9kWZHIHARQA7fTZsbk4dT1o8gCm69gLyGj2rIGFWUI8ACBeqenI5HDGxgIa2ZlC52AG8wEN2wyhpYUEpL9jdmdD5s6mk9mUAW59yze6NgDtLljfHBgze5plXYgDIlP46ch0gs4M4GQAceRyrF7NCDVz2eeNfp/loB8DHscms4BqhFaV6TqEM9cDqkGqEKMAGPVrXkdzDm0GTTRwq6yQy0H8YRSC2Bq27wbIrKKGkQ6MVWozhPvEc4eeMQZq9E2i6Sf3nzC/53rggx@m5ePpKjA9Y8p2d1ny8NGdJGtEzSJ7XSFqojo7gyZIhJHsxLBn0EPiLeFC@3hRbgGbLLmVrLIkkEXLsXye5WHYlplWACKpuQo4YPxrugq/ItPKLK/CCCowXSsls1jWwDOGlm1ySEOEVMLOD0k0uOfyTFfLPOXQtQc8WY8KLDG9zIolViqwEtwrrKJBiQg@z9RKAX5F@AG0CqCjwk8H5HIaB7bs/9Bfsc8dsIExtuxFUAIV0WMFlZUAKuCtAnStDFDgqev40@FHqK1ecdjTEVB9ZJwAeMm2jpErmRFjwqZU4KHs7CjEGZH18uL9ERYPJATiFcqsBMUXgRp5QAEorJWh@EKOV8QfmbYdZBv5mI2wLeXgB5iXgBZlaIUc0DOHBC3BD/zA9zRgcBpwMw0YlAZMRdPArWMRkK4IcUVo0mKeFzMy/GMoiJej9akBgLMDGBUpjsxMRSIBBGgxBqSG5s5Dh9CxQxR0BvgDLqUiA35WVlk5z8olBvSs5Bi0jwp4YW9RgY@qgI@KwKAPqNAJVMBJBWqrAFTVC0yIEVvVMR7y6pAXSKPmIU8e3NBwahF/kA96hwpFqlCmplWWnRFw0wpQ34JOvVQrQuuWIA7opgGuGnQpDbDVyhCPectAwzJ2Yui6nBAG0gFaBbs99EUgRgHwIbiQFtxaSef0M@zJyOgi1@Y5uwPMWsThUEQyQtYcVg@eeaQmoJIDMDgSAH0NeoBOowae@ah4WwUgTQRv9i1i1LYFPEyNKFTKUod8ZUymS7KpRcJospiOojCNh7nAQC1ggubQ6C2iSBiB2ShyGVrUMVQjnrsElMtjqA8c1p359hJI5MhrVJR5YtnLsDKF9U2jP7D80bslrnkqpGsaU8c6XpZSKGRjRDViEUWMWAkq6fG0U0uCaWs4QteyLloJ00zcqIFWUFZVQq9rDmbO0JQq5Rh@FDOdeVOYYJZlVniwZw2HMDcv4ahZqiZNmMvgAmFo6/pUiAKRulimZ8E0fpP1RiBYRJEVDr9SWcLQNYSxMLo4u0sgjcFsUMH5a2DNWfdmj2aPJYI60ak3siZh4urGxLHGpULm5WKsbxDl3pRzEXvGqy2/ci0nlWTJtHAuwJzDJcz4jA0T26c4W@H8i10X5leXpIcl@0w54QyZBqKtTvYw@9rARqFRegbOxDgvmTSvhnCsqcygEBAHTfcExVeaHFeK8WkC7XoorYK00zc9j2FaEHH9LE21/qzrm69nKE8t8RrA3G3CFD8wLDtCgOYRY0qCADyTPpS3WEV74LljmmzGOJXarjvZILbAxH2KgO65p@YS9eW8bkwmNkhPEG5y4Q2QOTVI7iYhPV4qRwgyYT5ocABIRYHUYXlmj2gfVB1y6yCfrKJYZVrjpo5QbsfEKh0GC4gcPuZxZrZdBXnH7DG9ofTNEwVDuOi1KnIhDqEwBiJVAKJrgMyMmBMWEaSbmkxi3lHYsr47Xq0an1/vR1UfWSgg2afGAlpvAFOrOTfGINkzFJ9h5LIx9BjegtgSoLtgte6zvuskpxGUUw@EWah0VBMSmJEmU2tsghbkQhZs8TwhjbM7YdZdQFcmauVlUns4JhcIJQsXCcUD8rEAPlhA7OvPekg1LNtyqAeBqOSjrO8Bq@RhwtRjrZYBPw/kukmg6cnowITPELWYouDz0R5I4D2CiLKq6figXvgys1APg54/dAfQ2U4tqDswLMi6hN0jIiAJoqC53JMFIjl2oPGxzSzWm0wYhMOkBN3zbq4Moqj7ymJvINIegSrRm3negs0n0BLWGFJNe@5gAL33jTkZAQg27rPeogfDExoZe4/Qd4nB9Car1Vz6tk1I46BycvDk59nQBLKD4DpALRW7/LICkwlVgUhhOFyodQygFFahN1kQWYTEMsfAdWUM77umT53F9Y6joY@F@eaQhgaMs8GSGY1RSIde6pBy0QfOEwwvhI8FCmsrg0UFveAj04Gh04NeCYMemg/bdJ8NQNmOibCobxi9njmZBv3EJXZmOTG5//FdlPspVAqAyf5I2L7Fdi/0Gkga9ZyYLIt6EKI@CdQRA3ltoNFLJHhEqifnLPbiUvGQ4uRC6eJLTLOCwUtxAw4TGhKoBBGTmE2RlSB3tHoj5IVT5DYkb8No82aXqw9h8eK9MZMGUdmIjQpsR5CVKAjx2AxDgp99GZA8sRFWYyUAk64EXAPa8MdrILsRknY/HiorhgxM8TqgY9dx10AFYkZwMclqDLUFdcZnyDUMO@qMNFz8lTZChr1cZMKJDObQycT1YGRwprOgFQVqsljvChTxVDRXpGV2e3VqhSkjiRP@FGdByDCxDegLOMRwpIJmZQCnACbGFWXgeS4vMYYwjXqCFeB3SqyfdyaYSx3HROXM8BYcCFQPpmcoaMEszwM2eIKTBJ@DwslEpn4Kc4LR7yNnRXLQuL9YuIw9@mDWteYXtfEeBsqvfOHE8NgAFXEPhA4YRKnkwE@maxROOWNRouJOpgpl5XcRElIiGZo8NQDdHiaJu8Boni2cXkpcGWJilomz6aAspsGBGbmMxj4GVeEidqg@YKcZH8O4Jl@NDWH6liS4SxhGmGCEImOE4YGcAYMQtMxKpd812FvgHh6T5gdcFQlVElXOR2WZTj8qKyAE4hKvr8yL8L0eOaTYrIY1wORUc5okVgj4gZSgjCIEKEowt2IASXs8juQaHjhzaD2OpbgokmZnkfALE0CKkLFA@LB61rQTiCs3b4aCy1a9Dp0NpClgm/10XKMNFy5l4NSQWCZpJChEnrrPpjg2UmmoLyY@59iA2AQ9td5gZ9ORByOO/OcCJAKyCg725JCwQTs/so5n/YsN7WAgJhJx1IHQZPWmYk2AyZ@PhvpVVE2uUBW03iRSFTsv5ifQlzovhWKDikEyz/RR/K0HqMRaOIUYBH11LYl41iBs2aEPFj07EAm4CwY750ZdQP84WNCKGFE2kAnCQXtppHIgOBw4HPZk/@hePRiLPFLpWk51JcB2e4ZNwduYXAzzPrh/@@n@05/vrIFhW93qxQDFypeLONXO5tLQmSl5Watux2EsAd/pXA0bM66mEYUgmknuPCYqLXowucxDcj5@@pWLJAFJCMlBJYAbfxdEGp4GhC6ha/ijC5MwG2YyUGSUJUzLpPsshBk5EHWMN0J8nszevMHGu4jUJAhHzOyZwQGEgcp9J8wnY@QFASyM6g74jEh5QQq1HNxwWLriKUN8PkKp@SIyJErHusxHj@8ePq0T2GBdTaIkij8FWcrw@jL0eXsGKvi6NMD@wNVjGXmJOMrThOtaAvd6KwReti3bAB8AoK4ju0yyx2HV/BHgfnCxbhQq9aIeQH6CcFGujMtDvS@KaAwPnOJ6qPKum0UpYjlZRUFrZ6wodnXa6hUKZilfiU9bvWWZ/ThQ2hyAeSCUGz2IOvYlDJGXUmQgVgfoP3twCXGfhEhQBaQQM99mMpXl2wJqL5LFkr5yABqaa5vyp8TxRCamFSUZ7g/IPZ@Uz1j6w7k1TeXS/KmmIS2Uvr9/X7sTJg6WrGklg5QG1MVxZvIGuM/X86GPOK7tDl22A3m4dBgWCGLTxmruD13nUgsZGIhVTeBWIfBfXLgxJjDXWG9IcaRccXWVbzoajn8KXFot6kgkohCBUii9/Mo4MYBcy3o/u/@1Q5hE1EIuF7lzdAEJYnmIXOjqxUIpgElQkBzgs7aC0bbhpdEeRkixfTusdMDoooz7y@i1gcQxZWVt@rUofexeovgrd3Gha0EI71rgiJHs/qMnD@4/Ony4/1lrqhUKK/58rlIEwkF5XZCF5BGnG47WHT40sVoILgFjw8PhBVxgBgpKuGs08z1g3DImkTkCG3oN33BNfeyOnKSfvliZU4yVXjk93oUe4uDjSYOMoGj3bVRGPL5rjfM59p/RdDrxq4oCo3w068qgtCqveq5tDBXKBxODbSsqqi73H@O6hr8uByDjL0yegy9ugeiwoBVEwx67oLzQ3jeyBpbi4GnVyraGI9CFcYPc9NJy1IOpNkofNATQlZWobsSAyQe0DZ5hO4m8a39Z1cq8X6s5La@IYbKV4Q9ptwYmqE4pmK2AFOkLXta62brJFsClEdJFIAkm79Aih89wLrAZCJK0aop6fkgc4ha4Xoq8gmj0eoarucCllEIuX1KLBQXUMlDTQGaVcM1NGhvT3kiauhLAk9wBrRvEeuHA7xnOQN4JHCGyIPfdgKrqzRetltMGAb11k3DD/efmot1U2@kau5xlJ0ifrkHvXake9t0wAPouOaFr0pNt4Gd94zI76xs0uvpMmY4nwZwjTdjDfRCk3rjAr/tmfOxhBiUeqeyspFUw8TtlzYKQjVkFvCGlFBhQMNNC11MQLwmEXhQPoecA34plYMvVjEhgWkxHwD90ljogV/qyhIvBesA1VlHBRWF5sgCWR4mQaUs6IhRGUIETDgFRSYIKhBIPxic5CvyoSYyVod6PQ89ykz5t06BohQu2/gTakda7ezhR@LhEOYUJOhp8OFFA/8J5gp2aSVzKN3y@YAqZguMGYX5QFyMItDEQLYo70QEL6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV29FyoRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBDj0AbGECoJmXlF9nlFeEkUslqlY8c9dRBa12RlqWtN@X6DO/Nw293qx@sGyXWNpwFoVLnY1EL7812zxxd6eWaqBeihBhubYxdXM0DAI25kUhUMvreP6qiPi@YwsnMSbloCfIndOgBG2jP5kpU0Rj0OevUhS049ZV/6mmJIb2BAXSHeYeVjTRw0@lFIgNWTFrRQEyzCkoDkjinRp7Tkg5G3Q4k76FrYs0Sj7k5M56LayZXSVLpGJyKSSb4PdZbc2tpKVpONZBZce@DaRdceujLg2iOXRC5MJ6OLcmTJhbFNyoFh7eR5M4Q8T7exD8xReHljTVJGs1rV21mjqQZPDZ9paAqgPKSW8AFwkul6HZ3ptNg4xW0jUCFidT/AvvOs51mTgAQfg0zC/fHhJQbDyzNrqB5fTZFx3QO91UQpN@UlW81cq906a/UzrfNkFnOna0YdVFTgn9PUWB567mwCsmMzX5WAvaaberVd69aTueROKlWWbCjISKdvlNMZg9M6lTShT6VarSSQNKBOszfyCN48q6XTEaEAj4EFio5tp5LyWRnK76bb6UwS8qaTWZgZ6skk0IX2PH2qNC5K8E5015oDKWFgwiwb39YgHk37Yzhcv2ZORgsvniBa@ANBHxfxl8dm8HQRTiRxRv2G54/LlCuLDaHozdOBfI3rhyiyTRZ8ghE4pi1l5ZBWOPWfSIOxOzWUT2TQ2@TYjJ3cSiqSBJMxxXBIVO2Hlo9D2HBMd@bHFzvXrsFi6RB6NJoBswxPymWhV1kTweyNXJbcvgXQWbTlhIwfd88kvgcXAuj3ZPghE0XBCPdrQMChs00W8EU6FUYLQyohwVlPuD1QKE5ey1FpNcrDcliQNXRcz5SAJJBDoINcdDxQaIRb4/dp8e3S9BPE0qyKU5llAke8a7sG0Zaz69iW1GQcy@8MMctTsy/YwD8GwB5l3hae2Vd2BNoodr0RzBBQG@TEWtRa4yBCcf1JX57OIauQwjk/HskVTJB7T1lf07RirzCohnHYK4DYI2gkVIwd0LLDKEmFyHTQyId8ZSpcJnj0@M4hX76h@R5neFzK64zd/gxE20B1e2o6wyw7hP5kOe7YAjKE@d8c209dd8oXGsCzaXGI6@3WeGYbtOx0cWXoynw9t@vatBp1VdZl@pnnG7bB18HC2P1PHoK68fzoWV2uxhIpxsn4yrJxKXR9sZye9@PbnrTlG@5Q@bxjitsFEeet8AAqspkgoogRs@D4KbRRGF7C8HBI4TZOEF7G8DEePQVxPVjIIG8UGCSsUEI8jopn74LAMzV3juEb1cAonUrpuOy6xPZM1Sj8ZDoYrATrFHwsIWuyl8F5CubHUlfU1DhKBZ4Iz6iupIkDKlKa6KjqxnQlSscP2MjR5ubD6BzEyLTD3c2nILHgDh5M@jbKVaA3oZbAj5OaIORPcKOGWDdu/7EeyMH@JSkWBttE4qmFxBYNIJjcFBRphG2FBcvvNRpCjhtsm/qcrbpelq/s7Db4RjuqdR7XKBW@MbDdARC7jVp45m9TMiwpmYySEVTCDXJQNelswaWqRidFfFrvFyhLTfAV0GjmWk5qzUuH7bdJxScyDJjYas1v5LTPQDXCg5vbN5WhWaNjVhvoVQtjkoEM210wCSQ@TMXXznsj4DMsM18lJbTPzBm4dl/iG3XQYRhX8bCBgnMS0YHS4NywaXnhWVI6zMuzIn@NHUO9BPdCkzYuJ4gdXI0AwfA5Y2@PsydvWROmvBPZn9jWtM3O5anbGQWHtZyLR1y5DOp5xsIXgmM2dbb/9KNPmrk2hyCMDdx8K/NWnIcnpUFwBkEJj7SDCw8LTa0pSQJ0GMLC@qoyIDWnfRpAH2DwAmosKiioEaL@1ny7rMvABGU5ZSLm/mKcZWb6XB7YxnRqOrzP8R3QzeTmW1VBMXUqfi/Y96iyHG0OgWRqYRygWGPPju4cPn0qQ8/1U8lD3ESqwnA0eiMQUDZVOqRkvPJVdqOfZDcwTxpXDgQYaqB9dIL80Klr0OlB/4DSkXcMTS8FgWnc/@lBMG25UUYuoQUEwiNfvSnRKAKWMtNQJwJWXYv/c4erWgGeVejxGaIkkDt1swq0tdLyzLFeyz5MNCS3QpJAWYX5or6dIi62raaDM31j3L0GDYuERqhBs8mkN8DlILHI2u0aP4YAaVEB84ZIXVGkpqAD9XU1bPo6BINIQxCC7PV37EUzJ1Xame11oOh8W3AWntc/BhchrIL2zbXFbqdovF8ayBwHvh3JOfdzUqcvvAhSZdvcIfJlb0oentkipkNHvFaPaq0eBINBhqyEVoOwIiFLSARvKgR9luKJ84POg9koIJVmZxHRNSQ5e/uWaMi2NUY0BJfKeGOch9onMKYHLtTmQfCWQlw6oNEanGXBMdsSxFDNWt0sxhguwisnF6RT6USM5@PSoeUcu7TlFLk6OVktoEQY5R4f25dz4jlYuq0kjXDgabVN2Pnj7oBuaxLQzkuwp08BtKYfyMIgRBrKU3rQ8v6aklfPsawUG5yQpZkW3Ex6fU1KqVKmxINu19qUFIiAR9PC55pkwKSwP2tyXlbD1x5wKQbmI2BcXHtZVv3iESi2QvfgKG/w/K9f7wP9L7fOCCYKXPyMHB2YurGlpMHGxgqyoodu6xuWr9HPbMsgwpDrOpA9w4MqGXbkWA@azgFIEkz/Y9zVCFoc@ibeQGq8optxzPmmZPhcX8i6fT0HWGZvU9oLR8J4UbQDBYpdn4jAhSDLpEzEungjmHO@CxRTsZGNXY9UeG6LUWfm7T6aTWf8DoLrtY1oTfB31dgMUuYKRlc1FX54/oom94zjWd@VJsfDSE4trkm7rD1tQ0sgDgQ70h10rq8@ryA/jB4@NyVbTm3KKT2u6xW@M/MnUpe08D730UAYX1GCZ/P7piRW8B5h5NhMNcum2wf2xAA6dJTgQIaCx12lGNGsC2S2je4CZZDRF@9l0eEG4Dj1XiaT0zfsbk8mm/OjJkn5K5X1uedyj9Nj3RqBwo/USnwVjSocHLK9plVhurLGhi1p/ZhzIzNfdzbiUtJoW5Xy4Psf9BLIlZ0cJ6TezDa8peuKLr7EI9xG2LQiHUwbT6yeC@LAhKklWdXCqSM2YRDLDE/nLQvCE810i53AsNaRMXyjRYpc61mA25viqdUNfeoDGBo/LYpncmOdRHY3UarnnuJvo/gwAtWU39fPaG/WYvUBzEmye7YB8/jG6WBlcRAXH6/pqKeWb9JtPWGP1yI67dlrw1eHQLjsF1/Gu65b@5bt@uwZ3a8i0NADKvD7@g4dp6VlOBIthsfdV/Cg8JjFskENe@jaxfJQMeC2sdVn3gD5fvD8UA4XcShVvYZDheKP66jBcyNfP1a84@saiN6Z9PCIbcx5xRS7jk0Fey@baweKAW7cra/Z3VyZcsoKX@rbUDBuuZwai/D5M0wdm0gbTh2TBYnTIN1hhkoZHFOPi9g/S2n5q0vrfxhTugS2dF0lYo17bJswWdH9UpMyLad@wRxqLvfhLGpgz8yZuVbReNx9ZeIb/lcoGR@OVC6oxnawUo@bA/h2TJTqTaAZfhDWOE@j70pmYthWz7xelFllahOQvieoOj8BxxN0XM4xdGaTlVZd0c6cp1eTbDQJh7TbX8EOY74oHypfIymtyOe@Sb8rNSau4eEZtXohl8sFAkxsx2XFc5UmpUd5X1n8vlIwhSxLXqbFXTYv5lxfBpElfgpyIwvSNin2lLhSURzLMacLvH8gN@26rv1FWgqYKr6z7IK2KtFp36ta7JK4E7zHwpZLFz4ueHQHmxYt@GwT6JZAH1Sar2r0@JbQB7WmhJueY9yQWvVevXwT22C6rhR8vxbXhPj5X3uzLBmshqhyWS5dOeq4hOp2Tdvgj3kxfxW8iqxfCW@VaQSbtbi5y7d0l1vxiQtMabIAYll90FJG5tgk7xVSvtFHax3BY2OiuYu/TdFz0@wp80OztynBxAK@4OB9ZQ85JixNXQf0qykeNUQ9xcbDrEHoJg4c7vqtJfL9sTE0ufmYqzjlcsECT9NwtW7pXL90UeUnaHqQbWkXZHOXgEF1bC788LkW4MNFD9p1Nr5@ue3C4O/hGugHjPZNp2gvT7HOyB05I3PEj65Hvk2DA/rjlJv7uQp1wHo4wtN0k8nKKfs4PW3Xtj@EnsgaOaN03cFanA7x/Vt8eewLweUv@wePaxfvjCnnHejYOGpG5gzmJd@duhNTIt@mpDYu9PD7Jh4ablL/rCtIV@r5QJHw@bPCv1a3HBrudDKhR2diz3y6UVaJXpu@Tm4a8KMpdC7T9YbyG3fclYNAOTi3Qlvg61lM15r2RvjeOu/Z5tDt9kbWdUgHtjKUcMmHez9Id0XKWEy6g8GybQF5vYWM/aUej3@Gj/ubGj1YPeLTWuS4Ql5Zt0JHb4ZLE@O45/PVUHSxKi4Ix0Yjf3@8Sm/gV1/PrOkSaOwsU7S8y7cl0LEJ9@D0xEbJil7TWLLh4FTFxl5KQjoK5JKZA4FH3VTs6jm32BDTdX7bhFC8loRR7FzKFyF3cPaHVget2LothK/0r5VDS2snOWc0G/qXGSZfru@DiIa3zcsWdJw6tmQNc5bhBI9NZNZsBd@zhGcHZK6ZeeWeSuHKTRVKp9qS4Vrw6MADmm62cQ3NtiY@vzNpsHErLjjLBLr4xf1CTpvFemU6aJi@OeBbIOi6TkQcux6eRAYZROrhTjquoCMz54IXZ1yOOwSmLtlsmThMu0lsWXtMaH3zR3Om9Nkjc2jgWesH1hQPa67pFdRl1x0vuhb2V2eGb311BjXb1NnQaATfhvTi1gXQtwbeQ2No9e6tNESEZEDg4KQnf6x0fwy63BanI8vHE02R44qFKexyvBNjr@uA3rAm5cV1@8hexnIA8Tcx16Zet7buThb4wtqCXFctq1tTWmUNnptUx02HwK5E4nQ2nsz84LEeBzozFV@FHh9TuH9qAXDpNbBWNjLs6fqV6tiSK0hhwaS4dG6Sxr9m2e6Qfa2cYyC0gRCGwvmajnMbpucneCDHc9b0RCr7A7c9caFD8njFXkPbmvhehWNNr17NmU7xcE74xMrwmQPfUFAe4F2@9UUhSEfrKfLgell/@Xb0NfM79Lxn7szrmeiMTJ7E1YKgVPMgPH2Mb3S4aLLlNK6l9Vwbhhc47LVDpuc6s6nkzZwrZ4XilbNCFQ1exboBS3318OHzdLw30Gnt66TQ0CTa0rXxwMCFTmY5IIht5qOrqUNd4g431fSUjgpfk2cf7Un1iF3fcdfpO08WMIF8sMIEzH82vmP2cNvw2rIfuQ9dx4XZaAKMcvzU5GYHVg56rM@I2R7gi/VAn/61xTwjsBsmIS5tGBOzC@1rL10fMhdxwHeMqbFhKqK1QdL/Ite1fcWyu6b3ihb9Yu5NKu0qQvfMOekWmzsMH4PStNfjIjGux62MkZUdG3/iug6/E7fNwUN9eDVXgamAbh@@US7jQfyVdYG1@tlqVR@f8FMiZp/bxdhUV8/suja/X3EmybH4mQDDs0xfeYBmFiismGcSSF/@lTykdCUPWapGIMmeGD5t0q9XNZYg1fkXOAI0MryeizthgeOK0zkx2wjXsOnobD8/ONAFws@BYxm9WWCv9Dq07HF3TLeNCkOsNZ@aXXwrqEsGRabG/HJj8pWhwJpC7ERXZIMgZFc4qIss9QS0kfT109aKHrVKVWtCN@LUG7fL6bCO5Fhm742Bq2Yu0Wu5Nr0SD3VWHpFzw1p1bBjRKrJi0Mv2a0fS6tE1EGhsU5qOPND5lelVy9uhpZc1@yGzsYmbzKu7MBtFV9cfUWXd9fvpEXP1TCkwNwi8JDI9yOVDaX@j5Ing4f/x7Y8VmIQ7xXxo/QRY1/U7@ID8zHOCx4f0wCeuPx1Y88eAN74FsImdYLUKkAUefGSga2dTJaD1nJnNVx@GsXNX4z6pYxIZhJYkm9j11JRM50QiW3TzyzVy@Utfyj4aEJ6afSkwxYA7DdKD8P2vKFnwXLOBGueNeNhTVThh58V8cPxzHXFPQ84A8pY7lSY@PZWJ/@T@g8dH8sRX185P@yN8O@KSHLdi20Er52JLUq8ML7bfyY@j9S1/qtx@pkoHD@7LmGADvfmOhgQP3JlbeWxc9wwNySrGRi0IY83pegHx3tHDB5nlK5osdTDy3LGZjkcfPHuWxTdNPn62Njqe@y6MjoE735j9/qGqptd03@cO7Q5u4p5rStoE6cgEbRQ64z1uGuZa4arnTsz@0WJifgKTJ3Jw/wOLL26s5CPjxBriKGSVjYSigcoqcjGfjp3MBmXb9KLnpvY8tibILXv0UPhj43EUlBx0xdPXSw9X7fhflGJYLjiJ8MUyqbnLvTVuylgx/L8rYqqqbqLzM2MA7coKGxtrNcG6/WHbPfmArWQzUF6kKEiaQq@SrGvPkZekMbBuBW@4PB8EgrO78RjMVQCi4OLaAX9qOgvDkWgv6yrxogq58VDblUm@Zn7AhlR0wucE7aWv3eOLjtSzVI@c6WsKPvJiWQ4Obt@/LsPTgJZXp/ro0XP2xPDRDsrVCeMYmx@A8VIyeiXhuhUa4du4ndr3AJR2JbzhZP14rrJnhtd3ncX8@k04egcVp3aybxzBQh8lMm1rbq2bq3p8XevJ@mNG15XNX@JwFytycNw@TgDo/bf@harmcmT9CJ9qjnuvaZlwgLMUuowFmtSLRx3dj1hDD@UWGQLSa7XRB@Ycj6Pw1eB1Sv3a@a14xdxXSm@eTq6KK18Rl7@ivEtxGMh0OadeAbBwRRwryFH0A9c@HbnygeGZ/przx2sRuqoilSsqUolx58BgO20sBu7NIj6@uhA81vbWI3Pq5Scjt2vl19Zhf4B2LtlDtNd@OT44TmF4dLxl6AavfHD/@vJOZ@bagh4ab9ZHEKc5XhsFTNAczeiViMvRqxukXZB5TWdocROP7LY7PSTfFYpZ9Mbz@rMI1uTObLIZY@CN@FWMi@x8JeGnoDO7pz67ja/GLcX0Nbo/no9bH75JpmXRwiBaOr13tB/2rsfPFC1W4hKLz56sBOPLo9PHz2Jhnjmfb1J6pfkmHXJtzLLUR0f5lWJ3Gy9O1hBr8/tGIG4AP46eG@Ugzuw@fnaZJaD6NpqO7TDmY8NZrpiuNFjfndKbhmsjnyzmdIxybUuP@Cm2dXFeb03wimIPE7JlQdm@0umgOaZOZ1OvPDI/o70HEIPYlIslHGhgeMmc50chhpRl40B1j5fCzwq6zyYjy5mvjRpvykOnSFOv/PXDYJ89s91T9iCyKrSJPWjrgRsnprOJOa17WVGq6FdLYfoFkWpTu/APqASPTU1ye5OgdoFn4IGIq7gJ5n/aU@6Gnk@09LXpP34WJr8@7YHt4vp935qNr09MYDOZ6xN6V7C/iwCt65Ph90aOR67nXJ807E7V6m3zA5HY@uCU40XP/QAcuoPB9YkOfff6RA9n9tRCnWV90kfuzEYLAuviDr3h2vDGbqPVkqvypkg06O6PvPTmeDwX6c580IGsiHlGGaVX1nQlMOwz8TC0L286suOmL8D92GVfQUvya0jx5gPb6OO7m9KtbtjMcIuf3gheOjcd6p0s9GsH@RtrSJ4PGXSONb4y7dLk333PdbgvvWl6XJr/W1PSPcO2rmVo4YEH7ZqjDzih8Xh2ol/PtUBAuLu5zT5ZzJfq5mrtbW50Yl3cgQZEGfZ66fAjSHg0XdVji378/Nm6I73cqgBMSvGPYvjZwKYYt8LBbR/4cvjlklTKgb6bXv1MXNyQA5qOT22j6eRtMtoAad@@ZVuBoQSIEEPTC4FpCLSwajkzE2078I9HTevbUEy9rhYqbA@/y1Zlao7KxE9OVrghy7CwJts@C8weVKvqOduqM7EqssDwRGSXnttWB8BoFRoqxaRjlW1PIWY7NJrA6DNB7C2jtV6ph8Z3wScrcfMxtcCsBOC0ffbk/pPDZ0f7R8@fNXPt88DsRFgLx4HSQuM2N/S@CJUP6AY6JP/SApk7saE4@oQRrhH7Yb0YfhZttWr1laotKyXuYZ7tM8dRFLK8oUjngJ8k8tIoFiUhCOKwwxpTAwVGV6rcCAbZ8oA24qBFKhMarcpy6wqeGKAPbTtB/MWvCFIsfm2yit@bxIID4/jQkYeu2w9K9E12/RWWeHf//oPnTw9ZiOCy15xa/emoXinwbydwa0DQTgOLjiLXWTLIkoS2qteTd5NAmKScZFWylULfLYCODslC6qCVlSD3DkttE3ygYDJqFOW/fl05T8r4Vk0a0iZDpJJQLPR56ihbW1vsCDoJu/P0/ieHTxnif3iHgpFECIIdoaGGP/1Rn3/5JzSkFn5p0xuT8kKGqIS4sZbQgsnSyArSnMbuZPP3NulLO2TKJPrET/SNMkGgL0BBvz0lM6wX7GOmyWQd/z5oYL40LIi6UPi1ENzARVOkyBYt30JDKojDAC2DrnZ2PPNJBnllto8fE8VPlhr0GSpAfeZMufW9wAZXAnqaHPGcLNsmZPlHq8RYwuTuFnT2rgl6LfMdC2bWaZW9gp6Im6RVbmhHkhrJS1lC0FVySagLxRJeMiXqKy1Pef8r/0wZ1hi4p@D@duCe526D75cC3wDcv8zdLxTsaJdNjy5xiSOEFouDGnBEIvoj7WPfUHW4caMl4dBCashYmTWGZjohqmNyXgK/S8CPl3BSzU@g0aC7QYsFRo14eabXTqHJ5KqiYJfCtRaZBARzzs93XzCdXCwU86oCSEonIUD61skQDVdwgOl0FYaJcGJN6i9Bf9/d3WUiLria9WKNt6yy7bzQxZcRotuQVoAJGZBrMsgDWZY5IK4RZIPZJ6OmMStyr6SaRMbVd2FaonicvtDvBIQQWQqIxWlk4scz5vi53SmoIYEJ8C5@oDb2HaztAJCkwpxErrQoBOaAHrlT6D4wSJdfuuPmgPD9Bj4FomFbn3@EmixvY3@UL4@spRWL8INbwViTkQdwUHru4mwab1vxUwTxDEFUxXXdt/mCtaYtp63wvsmgm/5gTWd2wP2LynBDn@X13r9s9Dh10WQxEovdeua4uLJ8FyrDUpqi6YpaTC@rlM@vrVJQo6AYqA5aVnsLxQGbApbRM61X7sTfPzi8//HjJ88uGfallMmLyYDvN3YzLUnONtuRIxmv1mqT3L6rPHt4@27YEEukizFuDIw/qIl6VU2WG0YIcvkC4sWqrcPwYu02Y/wpN1FyEV9duwo1ynQJDzX3Bcqll4Cku/Qq78XCtfI6ahUKV6G0hKfEQB9wOwyXUE2lz86bbVDrnETyck9YMxBeJOQdHATgavk72wp29suVw4pFn4c/wg9u@vGxqK8fi@K2jnYj0QzM1D1eWtYMAmIRsfqGxQCLFGQlTLpx9D3mQvrS/qvGP1/PDU7GzenFEC7mrqJ4DBRVFWQcD7nI0np1YLh5BCqXbXWF0IwhN@Ac2pmNbDdzE4SptBB8hokXnOLv1rB5dS7Tid9UGrkdwcqyq2xBh/DSAgxolO6ezED1e@JO@Gc56GTXHTN0PXWB/d6Z8ZVgk308G0O6AT2emrTLDpxbgsxAyWSEKpelgEsEpqDnGTS2DeU10SB0UHF53C@k5ml5ZM771hB4eyqdBY52Q1XbLDIXjZUm89BOUqQ2W7bClUPxI7SuESf7F7IZPl8iYDQN2XL65jyVPE2mq20oH8OTp5@eJNPiur5EtssDY979i0bMI/RL6tWcxJgGozO0EL6OW1Qql7kEhF0EzI1pht8ErFTkkS/QN17rKLk/m3oPwAliRGowNiYsNXO4IVKZkTfVSjlZstAoNbiRY4dlMqRQwYMiZEY5B@Ti83fKcBYspdTxM8AQ6jt9fLyxJqypynIb3FRImm3jtzoPQOJC07xpAZRgyFIlsHXsQqBmAEZ8kMi8g0MejIe08CBzrmui6dOFtBnpIk2o1qxxk8W@vboqOYqVSjVo0FWuWGHQ@y6zQ1kBsJf4XCjXA3UDG2VAM1B/ZSGxZOSXOV6Cyk1wRO4Fxs0AnUTMMHlo84wBrKXZ8N7Iw1/q0IGxAvJBtfr86G6nnFZEFhlJG3pWHzfL@ec9IhUv@CAbDFNlJWmyxjW6jzAbmqPtcCtsaBX1Lg0Y8QJLTcTJEJj0DpVlf9k3VfXKXh9kDFoBUuZxAgheJu@E4NCEcLjotCZuPbP/6U8TKGyktlX1uOOdZJKFXA1uaq3ACuzGdkuStpu5@q1tA7So6et5C3RyZSd/Yt4ZDfr3h0pLFJnO8oqyc3Z2lry788R6UWBFqW9pxdfzxble1F/Pz3W1/Pp4ohab8ut5WyzXs8ftVrPNnjz57F3nXVqcnyxei6yVAl3z4LGo5sVEtcLO9op64riCHykH9eaYvYHreMDwn9xv@jG3ge7uAFTYpMgSrRZQXBVLoqI0k234J3X/JVxc8W825Ia81373Lt00jOl8wSzLmvj9PvzcEUiQWvoZA335JnB6nkFhLXqSBgVXYTwHZrdvDoezQ2Nhze5Ob8kluSxrsdWF3Ydf@zS4ap8@f87Yc/b8@ZunG9Yi2plMSpKa5J5fiKt2jEICPzP@pz/eOs@ePens/uk3xoq5hY/H@Pj2@UN0P1MLN7a2bty@nc9nNU3j7idfe/Lz@/v7@TvZwpNmYS8v5bZ2/@SPt7Y0bVdTttq@r7aTzePjz0QtlxflP/1hsvPkyVd9v6H/H19/11DxVoLbCSsBn4BLZyo48V6Gn4oy1odeiTcJ6OVqYkF/nUQYfrbF1MZe6b999/HrxDTR0JRPPXhOE68TxXKCO8EBPj30nSQaiV1MVjxPLJR6vQ7O0n/795C/8THAwZjFLtwahRBWcZFoSHXK8jbRKIJD1TQo9//6@tdjGHI2UScxLrxusSZcYr6kiXttuHbo2hXQ@KyUU5QwnTMdTU2XqeWb6k30WOCBh2PiVzzMaSuhlvPs8S1I@bSZyWTackeCS35Bi0SKqmotVb0J7EC6sVOvSzuMm9fV9cJN/ERAmpa0hi7MmObNT1euxKd/L9daMLW/B8BPhURx69bLO40G1E5v6DuNDF3BkKLRVSqLrntLZFn2MgnKSLP9ktUeYFRDzJU1MZvN3urwoTFHqknzcIgk8OL3RCIKwcHLLoQ1cNy3WRTOc7HLeVkc9Np0iUO8/ux//bPv/dl36e979PtPaKfX6VsDZQcSncDgaMB1q1rtNRpiwxPPWuhvQI/KVcvVstI5b6V2mo32U6bmPnqbLOjJZwznARXLaKVbTcrfoGIbQfHobySWwQ0e0oiHBRE8MQXAM6AUS6xSjdwR1Ri7kA4m2eCNBql50mhLKBrVpaZaLLQlnqt5CxpH1EoVsdNOSNsL4Dtau6EVtMfsVoNfbLTtMxex0bViWJEA38aybsuYpa8RD0o0wmyNZZovmi7AqSIkmk2lbdLM0AgRvbVV3SpXi1VN6TQ2X7VlDrwoqWmaT/zESSK6aizohyE9E1HPjIW9iLdE1Cws7MBsJe816aCtgEXAyOD/8UuLLkbNpRdVsRa4tI7IatA/NF3Shh0xp4rRYKOFfri24I/@4Yq8eN@ikCCYkly@tlhV3dF0pXCjeKjhRHvNFcdbgAmD9brd7pteF8QPw@gaPUOdGjNjbiyMaXfWnXenvVmP8THDlrX3dLfglt3QK0sJvaBuJ25ilXStopXxE496uaxXNL2k6qWiXspp5YJeruilvF4qAUC9pOmVSl7T9GJJL5b1YlEvViBcgzRFSKMjhFJBr@hC4l1ziz3lbK3NMuHVylx7PZflTuAkh4s/SXLnCSHxD3A1VE1lOzD15eAG8h45QR3HP1UVWAJkuLP2u53mux0Y8Y3MLnHbdkMKsISH3LnVzkjn501w12rB/24jctbo4i6oXPs8k9l90QDR5kWjmQGQLwKQssQIqNxpsPYuRUWlBcUF8cm8myy6t3bbICRJmd3mbt09oJ9MQ09qA@TdFWxv3crI4LoFABrbbZbOZLYlaQun3WYw@UDadiMT1goAtVMgiJyd/Yw/0CGBfZzvnjfOm7vn57u78L9L9/PgCaHnu5f@6bG8NqRZxreR9bSaSqOltAL20wa/rDQwRFZa4GjAE9I1da3cxgkPxRe5/Y/zX84u71EIotyWAWshscN2EmiGVk/sCImX7z//n/HXev/576EoyuDPrAqJM2QUyg4qshWuz8KNOQ8d9pBfDrjxF3oxBAMaDzHQ4TcH97oU5aXMqnw7IaWWi2kZZ/SOO@igZRuZvYSkK5wVmSgTtXJR7GTUhcYSu2KxRBz05y5dyWTyn7zUKqUkXwNC0ywvfd9/GMNyiSckrmk5VVLfNvjXR/iHon5u3fVPfm7TJSTeVphZBfqkGCeMkIB@lFAUSWoIicbuGN/dwV0YCRXek/pn0vN9CVdojCntsfX46kP9/mG9Ummg@mNuP6FBs3NnB@4q/B9uQS1YawBJW4N6bwyidWugF7QWfqkiIXVf49@DN/jHjnr49/Q1/rGjN/j3dIp/7GEX/45e499@F/@Oxvh3@zX@PXyDf8@H@Nf6kq6rNXH7jAiTUSvq@fZcJALVYMJqtL409RZV@uyaqO1poK8Ga1gpPV9JJ1pfMuc9czKtBouN@CKV2ZvWjHql1q1rQdLgFDjGyJYfftc@WFusaiyNq6B6peB6Eh5ZhBsEZPSK6nrJn3znG99I1utJKUlfzMpDmNTFRF1KBF7ImeeY4JeIAT9obt9P1m4lv9Sk9YVCpd3EyDZECIk621a31Zyd6@XUrtoFh8VyHsuNciO1r5IeljNZbpFbsNzYVfvgMuEvBy4rN2C5Ics5OQeSQSy4pp3cFF0DeAzhbwCAPPiz8DR8V831GBRkoyRKHwdWO5gz97bTEposycSXJijSsirn5KLVxu@ZNcWXL1vKTlurlJmM3VruNF@2km2xJeI3LrRKnnUX5lbrpQjyRk7k3R9DWML3QTuvJZRWS@GEB3JRS56fdzqHj@50OgpOhC1mNjK3MsDYb92qA6MPHnuJRm2vVaXpIpwyEsruXquhS@guZmAW0DAs8wWvJUR4Nrao5u2Xpy9Bn0mdolZzegKP09DxaQtuHa7vULRy@mkr5iWHopye8tRrIKw4lnJM/B/UwX@of@sf1//D5yzNUs12OnV2vpuiK41/6fTZ@dl5cG@kU6nAk9qFPwwAP2Y5O2@gkxKdgauZSrfT5@c8DO6p9C4H2IBidhuUd5nujCWiEqlUfkv9/T6h5OBqJWtsXid1P5/Ta9vzt2@57l/I0VBIAGuKTv20WvNcLg2MKvj@Du5hG2/paEW6Rh9f3e421faf/JC@sbSXpkSFfK2m7jDu0fJarZYPfaVyrVYOPdupVOXy1cjtqUVQivL5dLpWA89eCDYHXsjbZO8yrM5acG/fvMkLKWtBLQCmni9mcnjaqlYLSypAsaZv9AKufXb/MX2eCHhFIcGQJQSHTlI5@rwZ8vKkWBVv3kz1TXxror@3n755U6vk3r6NQiYTCFJXgjqdvuV1Ohiuv30rdkQ6p1MpgD9XfvtWzVUyajLteqlH@O1VKColqeyG1qBSK8CntXwJogMECru7xXyjUcxDSLGchDascSZdS4rJmpg4oyqo5RLnYCIFJ2BAw/zon50nqA1ZvpBOAfNLg@R4nsA/D/kkn58KhXQtn8slzs5FnlitVHjqNMsXU@VMJfirb6VZA6Qj/ocinp7J75R2boGQjH/@fN2FrLR2ZtbV8/qZWcWV/vMazPC@C7INGvYxb97UK0CWcq7WEjqdO/tH@51OHaYglLDghoHElAW0d@Qlq7Vb1JpqucASyRoPlJLAyVkZKKtoOwW1jMQQrAEa6gIxQeCa2hbbEjR64k2ocGlqCwJB8Vnle0IfLtZnXTbEiw1RiWQWs@liNuPxdO/1okQuv4LYyEt5Sc8MQ8zoEoJhp/NeCRPvkwf7B4dHWW1XYgnt7v5BVnv2/HZCRW9h6adoHf1PD/fvPH4OGZ48ONx/dvjR/U8Onz@BcJ@dLq9oUginhmiKiLnW@E/Zp8Ir741hmoY5M83O6Wx2@pq9sqyOBS1pz6BS7tBjvtmBukyMZb1q8OtZvvHqleFN6GLvf/Ct9z/4797/9nfe//a33v/2937y@fe@Bb8fwe87/Pmdf1cp4P0nn/@L33n/W78Ngf8Jfn8Ivx//5PNf/zr/kf@P4PdfYmF/FPxi6fhPAFi/9JPPv/vDn3z@y9@H378Kft@//PuVH6//fe@bm3@Y77u/c3Wa7/x7@P0uhxWm/c5v8TB8Xkr/WzzdL3///a/9B/7/J8EfOn/7/a/9Ed4Czz///p/8l/ff@I@aVv6Tf/v@m999/81vvP/mt99/859q73/936q5@O133n/v9//yD373L//gf6T/H9H9dz/k//33//mf/y9//r/9@R8Evx/D7z@A68d//h9hkP7N7/8A/7/7@3/zhz/A///pX//N7//q3/zSvyHHb3DH//2v/h2//9Wv/Oe//s1v/@WPv/7Xv/rjv/6N3//L//2X/89f/89/9d//3l/9s29g4G/8@C//8Jf@4hvf@otv/su/@MbnG@7fuvL@@QeEf/4PEPLheH4InA@p1xcN@fxnwufvQo1lKdBPoHf/4vtf/wXo4L/G2Ptv/Qjfh4Xfhv8faSql@RH3/f/AoV2uM8bkwAW/X33/re8gif4HIBH8R/T6duRZieGeby89QNbfXJPpF3/y@b/8IfkSZrVB20g4cZe1cmYHlJudSiWYvIMdJsjyC6vQIgBBSd9GDrUS923kbe9/8PX3P/yn73/wG@9/8Es4c0v5SnY/K6nXbM9BwsIHpMOExQ9Jhwk/g/I7GVqXkzKfgW/rs0JZdxyn9tlnnwmdtwq@eH3rLfsM/thn4cV4FL6YHUSFcRiOb2ozCG@@fNnGPd1YmKJy4IrGn0EUHrmHkiTtRmZPUTUeZb5VtnkuVoMAvay3Yqgrg8FOFf4Y3KrVnbOstNcCoY@yngtmWCU1gLqlMNXI6ju6AQmVPE/Hqs6tXD5T2jEM0GIzCDdD8s9OKI8VdDbPBEXOg31fDIdE8x1yzhlfzJ9T9FyY0/Yw/JcYKzOdMYf/1wSWIXGJLvxAbegkR5Av3Fomp1CAYjLLrQISEBmX0HZ4CG2YU7n5CsMazOeZOWje4IASMhB1GyT/ej2DGescRfDyyjTKjFDJZOpQb8zN82Q7ZQQxv01QIGc985R1dupznjGD8BohOTICBj0VVU3MlOt3oMD6/A5DWAicwL58WW@U6/MGgnvHqZOZZ24TTgisnpk33oG/TjAhn5C48w5QKdczmUYZC8RK8ubJdngjFahyVPcMywRtAE9872HvFmM3RLUs8l2SLSQYT433zDI1JoTkEN/K7ATVof/QSb8dIvgWFRWUwnj8HsnHe1xkxgQAV5JkWWbww4MIe@wWRM85qAwVC48Mh5ChHkE9IApguJaUETLUvhnyQPmJ@s4XvhAYVmZ7e1tINERdfCwT6RSFecdVegkEz0WiWlNlYrEiYrBJb8SEuED@GpW/ncR9xSTjgNmNDP/durXDbkA16bkME5iU0d28m@BQdjMZUQP4DTcjvABdSIB@SoDeCvK8TvuYGSGbZUyuJzCOPX78OECCAl7UhQx0c01X0Y/babPZLAE5ZDkrZ7PBU6YnBciBQ6bY4ClvI3FPPWtqMk3L10BlqzEMYnH9SgVtGwPfvXsHrUIHzar3QctlwZkzLV@mSAjgdq9sexG@OqXlKwJfBGBqMc9YihaE4UozfEcoBR0pLfAXFDga4ZVKauVyklIC/eXUTngIsagiB@AvY9Fr0KxQWvECNnEvruzx5WPcTI/eguL4pcqFdBh58JgdPH748PDR0aTdZgJ@BHc2NTsTz@2Zvp/CuP1Hd/i7LFqlmE40m0iVo6qGHEk4rOawo2bu33l6/1mVcSoFbZaietRoHzqgS0UVEpPJp7uJ4MyWiF8ydcVneK8uSZHSKsAt04mGkOiZqAJB58N/@NWEh/7wtjtnqVxWFLNqEdXRNO6nAh4/784Y2tnmRrlgEOIbLvLuLlFAaJxJsf0bDGiwp5rAHZJKDqZXyqGjxB1qqYgJ@LlIpguNZ4dHAProMVO1nCw0PmNzGVGTzoWGXbdNZzgdbeMBQ7GVE2O1327msvin6Trc1XwxqxZK7a0t@0zCglrUH87wpOg5eM8krPCX4WLClwX2ZQiCC8rA458sWA6//7gWHIBE25cpfgpSVAswgtMCLulzcMIkftVg4KzuiAmJra99bcoajcNHd6T7d1Gpn49YeAZQsvrySKYO0Z95JsUOGetbn1j4MVu5b/kT21jAqARqJM7PzwcA6f5dpjU08vIcfbyf9yikC@7zuSEknGq1/k7Nl4Sn@9XqO13TBAgQdhQ8ZLgFXYVOaOwo/K/mQyG6XlaACaqiCA9d1wXq6ELVFBidx3mXq9cl3lv1vErHcQT8PpIxry831oO08xvLtHqOp8UYiGDDqcdyYVyJxwW@okA@IBqeQMTT5EK4Apa7eVPHRRk9n4tWX6jG7BzaZlvP60hxfMOrnciXgt0iURTbCcE2p6xfB3eiBbcaH29qQmToQ36kl3NCopmA0Sc02836//t/7abQnv/j/QeyNJt1YQ5MLP4LgjENPdnKnyA8dB8v/x8/Hse9V/6PH7sPH7tjF/5hlnoohDyK/mu1Fe/V/wFvQx5Sqwn/X7yCPcrdSUPPqbvKBJwGOPO7igHOLjgLu0oXnBY4K7uKBc5ZQ1dzu8qsAU20yy2ZMzSUVhen5hw/nMDDxIZv2gMZ38Wri1SAJu4GXwZphBkb/Xrf7c3w8FOtL1uOY3po1oRnyOfFmuugjd16uDUIM0z6TBjWT8n4imDWhzKabfMcwxb6ctftL2R/urDxrTbb9epJ0EqSYcQSugniKq7L7ul6vtpkbXniTvYErVDKNNUcyBn4U8tZLbtl7pVK1b7cs03D2ytUC@VsH1@YCzZu9wq56lD@7OGDe9Pp5KlJb9Ht5SuQAQ2doknCvXK1UID@K4qZJhXTbubaMp9qpK0t4M@m0Zfgifu6vqSV25C5b3n1ejK5p6uapFb1XPlcWBIOaY41bAiYNYM1yyLdzwJuXnVcByaOatbIWmdEhepgMDjfOcssPYJxJnEf0OdcMrLds8hbk2LpqmyWlaxlJIQYAyD3WbBjXRW1QlmsNWtLf6ko1trnwq2x2bcMfHmulTu7nKsIEyyHmoCCWkw4r3quO612zYHrmcuEuloME3KELifIi@dRca0clnh2ubhiLNH87DKUfEE8j3KFaAnn50B3Tmwge2CmvkGHzJtqJd8@hOkEus9uaMEekyVevBASO08/0RsNaOqzfEnLF/IFTS8WCyUNZIdKvgi6eU7NFXMFTQMo@Uq5UjqHfq0o7xL0gVp2cBb29yp9oidlVLmN6Wabpd89suyzsi5xPFLpGkxSiXdC4sbTT7RGY/M6QQpkrU80qVHXCxVw6ejSdAEZraZJmi7pqqTq@H@NQ8P/D0@vwb@Gd8ila8IRWp57BDIQSHgOe4AWrKYuO3LxG4ZDdtvsbUhxMDLoFYADz/X9v0Oa24ZzzKPuWNzcexR1z8APufpjazrakOL5ZIxG60zvHwzC4bgLCCI/5Aluw82zXXddghJ7/mRDLR9GH1gBYvAvrEDyp/c/uncUex4d7h/cE4rs9uNHdy48CkGiAntwePco8pZ4bJi1EIH4@cMHDy56g0f@8fOng5nr4U@4@/h5fnmLgvANcyEP12qiKJiABDf0kj4B4iEo7IVS6FAFfC/pZr7CbgbOQnHpzKHzU/76vOVH78lwSwpV4Sh8p95gyGq7Jutx24S4qkN2gwONTy1VBGHCHPeUlXKs79q24TF3MNiCwJGB7webqMfYNvZELPrU9ez@qdU3t0BmgTIqoA4OCAnhHgAZz3pk9gYkU7RCD9Oaw3CftGvPTDabsI2B8MAgdHrWcAST8KkbJhC6hsHg90UvyG/Gr@nVAVNeBoVdirEvJxcSQiVRFsUDUbxnTI2aZ5Ze5KrVJx5Mxv7QbBzOobvC4DG8Rbac1cWpeJdVnRc72hA33Wx3glqnP2nuzED03toC1Xmv9Ve/@aO//eNf1Vq5g1wBFwx39x4@yGsLEBpUpdatvwNFftx923jB9vLuLcZQXEctTu4kqsD6QGVhpJUEmotM2q5WKRfKFV0rZ8uVcr6gFguFrKpl1VK5VIG8ObWsFsuFipot5ysgpuQrEFsAtZPrPUqo6Cg7VQDr9OxZ39wlhVkegWbM983Zm5SRZgkj8s@YaEIeUcDFjCnZYtix6jDDMjXH9BIDiAbrscTduwe5u3dF8TZ68OjQQU4U@@gplHO50m1RNCnmoIwil@jyPGW0/StOuSeXuw1NMOMA8LM5ojhCz2ERl4NF0ULPwf7du1jOAD0a5odkxzyGe@zQU4JkDnpAHSMAryNokGyfl5MnRA/Rg0VizF0ecwBxovhRiA7GPOXJOIB7YU3390XxPvfs72PMAVW7wBH9Cnr26RJFDzwwNERxCI6hB4NSFLvgxAEiij1w9RYGhI3BhV9WcaaGKC44eZBAojin1EbvWBQ7YTgW80mATQGpWyWPymt9izwV/BNFLUQak@mRRxfFfOTJQ93u3fvEGE375pBfC48/e1DTe/d0w5rPDu92P/qoOxx2vcX@4UdPMerg4B6IK4uZ1x12g4zdDlwu5Dq4pxnH48XFC2p9v9OpGvbaqK90OnnDuRDVWXRMxBByvQbMgmuIBY07BxB1cK9zy1h3BoIAdpA3jOHZxev2GJ63jS6PCi@Koue82xVr2P0VpZUSUKHAwww4HI@B1zrZsdHz3Br653WWy6JIs2gWc@0aRbAxKAa52jnGD1J4N3ANMX22aM7ruXZ9Xi8Fhw4HKbE11wqWmN0a76mVQnXL2FO1fGZeRXMw7iDJkpK6x1LqzZ03LPUovaeBkrAltvb2JLGptveKpRfIfqp429PUcjWf01iae/VSFfLkkjnG8JZultp7pUJ1mblUyhiKVi2VQGwD@kxh8u/iql2HpVKnpnGcTiPqtDQE9aGKswVV2qoNUvPsvM6RZIt0bV5Xa/zzAix3AVoq1cdv2cx6aMKccaBDADjfy1Xx@ExKVCtlEXBQlFQ6HfFABVzLdbZPv3p0fHT0GUmIjWDd6olnIjOrBd6P7h3I9x@HPvwOjXwXJVfXkw@Qia3EcBE2DDoCnUW@B3Mu6H9hGL6F67m2fEhHR0H8DSNCU3hyYBNePrq3AufZyD3lJaMRkxoZFnZ6JsPP9Fh9ZtQb4DL6LEVYMSN9SrN9p9God@pjsvMBVQxzfYXRN2yWYO77HPfItAplP8M3U4OITj13DpPNPDEHOJ06k9SXY7f/Usv0an38Os/t@m3MXOvAs1sz66bnuZ4I2rdYG@w59ZnjGwPziemh0aD7j7dB9sDXVVMDZqa3WesQUx@gZnMuNTzmLDF7NBunDKnRTa8G4eptFIDESX01rPQZvUHdqYvieW1QZ6kXkPQ1@L1tlurLt9N7@RrQ6TbrpCEo93LwcsA0VszXSDNJISwYWUQfrLfB0vXGV@DBYR9Xq4BN0NDHABULA8BWnyIg9cQ6r/XqNktJbM7SRKR8bVhvYva3eNuVYGqXpObbttCQpE@FBgzf2iJh1P1Zlz7sxnJdVcsVa3MIU0v52gia13gxr3n1ycwzazZ4g6Vc/rK4UQOiAu0AzJu3qfe/8PX0rlSo87AagXqLMkFH7tTnNQdNRUPHqOt1iMg087ks6PxwK2VBBNCKWbWY1bP5rFTCUJj/s4UsBIJKBOJIyk6JjInZ3Dwnq1nVVLOp3Eur/zKdPU6BlENEY@ns1D10ZmMGIdBU2DfJC08gT0bbsUFV67vM2JWoswLXqGHFgOojNrGyIwT11DRsypFOS0zfSdnbKUyzfTSbHDbb1erhfPJViEpJr/eKmVIu8yadrqW20nXffC00akIDGQzVerIFPTdY5Wb@bNyEVgaXWtKqzWYXq1jKZfWcDrWzOm@Hu2JDbGdzW0UVmuicEdtgnG/EF35RAFqGTTooqtsmNJ1a0WqCTKuwelmTKkphp5DjK8E8pzAJGBxSkqVaYmgYIZVMlrRkMp2s4fbWlhhsTwBPI36WBAabvKnuiSCbiVWxomGCJXOkd99zIXYgnZ0LKEeyPGjCZ8L52fluQ/iS8AzfaN7VXuBf6cXD/cf49yUIqoC3/OLh88fPH98VmELHlkF@rG3V5FqnBh5JbtwSElXGgJO2AqttyhZjX/RAdGa38YI/W/gKDcAV6PMPTdamg4qmhWoe@wQtguyxJNTB8MZNTdPbTa0EUyFw0zCppqk1wKKTwHd05AY0xvwM8NvNNPBl2q@wxcLISOHawM1qY5jZzmmLxElHLFZ0/i5oQ80ds63kzR0G0o3EEifHWw1tJ5N8UtUzyTtJPZ84SbW2Gxl1kVTYTkZbDPCMBe7VK0lIp5k7N/Sd5PNMtTzMVtUM3jW4V5NM2krc6mRvpSu@QE3CEhcWK/br@8On@7XQd9Aoa4vgJeDEi45YLgUotraBZFrmxWruBsy/L3CzpCXgGx7JxFmSJZLnyfNmsi0kbtGrxhp/1ZglopeN8ZRDsPen54ssnaikA1@pkvBT0cbbl5K3Eknc36r6/rsEdarw/c2vvNSgPyccNwwA/Q8X52C@LRRwayehvJz4X9PK@sP7j5073l1TSLS23m65uCUXriXD9c75@KuMTYDESdaqJ@b1fPDChNpoSOquhsYVS6wKU8pALUq5tw0@aBoUUdQg5v0vfD8/3wX9iGk5FfyaVshojYa6A7JKYvL@899DM1lnh5/sP2BJ3J752z/@oVb62z/@13QoM3lOWzaaXkpASnSqxVLi7GxydnYOF48rJNqJS2dR2kAfRTUqpR0ZaqOUDXB0lASnI8hUJTWd8KVEcBC3WJBSKVXR0jt6OZeGmLeBGbyUliuDN9zfpCCxWBDTicOnVkFTb@3uQc329LxW24K2VKPXxln0t2v6FWic8sOXbxkDT6/RHw4tjVyKwqrvpN13TNpl73Br8Z20xV7WG3iWRsWXzcMNtR18iRX3q5ONjLKTZKCLsUbzvHbeztCOHGm1L3ac1gU6tLbwFanVoB0H/swdn/5Mk7wU4IM39Jk7r3wxtZNWlH5fvLyGt2uyQgO6yo4CWO6E@2v8T5Ja6fe/8OuaVvzbP/6Vt523nc800GMrlaKqJX76092ZM/PNfuOnkPEKo0ihLkoSKFovQkekwzJumNQKckUOuQfq88xBeZ2nDzVa1GEZCDfW0DH7pNEKJyiQUYt2uF3OfoqS7aDNlCzJ@2QHL10ThFAW5vK8N@xlCQbbQTvqzXZaOBO@jFEw3zPQCWrCl5egIGAMM7zb6/j2zJvQq2Upyqe2s@wmZIESvow2T7fI1kswWUjANZWdy1k5yj5RjYQ3NjZ9Hy2owjwnfBmyBB@bsBdsYqBZIkxpOTA7yZiE8KSIfhPKbkPZNs/QodAU1Z4nyDKOHc/kgJgvfBnkFaKCBWIMs3YhQQ3YyZeBAFCHVADYarNdpqfZmZXJ1JbmWc8ZNDq@amWEJlEEzIbQ@miCJ8xcw3QQBOoFft4c@0XQwiBFxgJDIBwGP4VSBwUFs5MPJUOyWfTBoAAW2QdMUdXYzZtLrOp1q59mVCOEf2xNcC2O2sFZjysACzW9G/2qmGVo@LYWhkbdDiieIXSh10nc4m0tlpWJ6D0XBPj/4E6LPfJCU1FEDSsQtBcfFT0gGWRGsvM27LHdOlO1UppFyPcA9x4hRYYpIvW1Nb8ha5@FkeeA4U8T4ccDgVkdxdc3g3570SYOA2l@hl9uQ8uInBkEtmy47UNkevenYe4oF1TFsin1wPJAk6LjMaHZ1ZSupjHb0kwt4UFvmGh5hi96FNL4oFyYmsHTQPOhQTlbZPas50KD@hPXIXujZA8N37OBHgE8KjDVyNGeOaf4pc@gbShzHCOfzDRiz0eMyX6qi4alKC8eN@l6oHOHtMkycyiz3rjPtApLUUcjk5JOBC5NmQjhLgjkSOOubY4BpWemSS94@lVFGYKQNuuSXc2HFvSr0V0LZh7HV@5wAiun1rGlHKHJfckd4Hug3EpRAuU6HH78vEpgw9J23WNmW8cmX7ZOrdh48hmoJCBVZ4Gyyx8QtopnrDQ9iwslapangl8JHiXuLGdjebdSi/Tlp65upTrYom9p8rGgVWzzxHBi9KXrrRDo4v7CD63Eka0z8MsRyzUD@1D1JFp@iQyfCYG9uzqZWpNxO2SSEhNiaCcOncLEM08YatUCzjHANHuhxSUcxVDbL9MEQGMPRhaaj516VbQTBph4/VQPhl7A4B12g@magAm5Eb/A4B7AwKavr0KHOMiK9fCnfWgYmfYAkK/A6Bz3IQ4t1ATdD/OHvRvdZNp32b3ZVgAOJx0qq874sAg9hZgHRwf2Z6r6FkQWAcM1mGylxAyAzYhpkYOO8l/Mznu7QLykyi5DyjKEEJAaoJCoYCDLQfugsU9yChBx2/D5d5sC47Knp6cyWTyeeZZs@viZSt91DFuZDC2QhF1lao4niunD0PWsnjIJ4S5dEv86rTwZTfbmKM/WKzcX/CkIA78eHDxLJQd@EifHE/wK43BM1hHRLKFPHequRV9w7aWCc3C8/2nt7FnY/6rY/6Ry8hyBMIZg5tlFtpcFYNlu7zg7OO3XgogTGpAAHFrRDAPRDrkXesZ@6LImgyiFO0U@GkV17WPaVQZIIl9RXhbNaximXITewD@x5pDJMU/ZvucZixTFpzE1duDUgsQetoBpn2LAid@0OONGsa15c9FeyT6PssOkFp2p8ND0oXB2NVBuIR3j5zx@DvFzHj9fFhoW25y3uUiGQedYHez1aDE3TIlgFmGac25NfBlDkEEOZyoHgSkXK2Hn8OvVKXdIb@6DdqyHHQP6xAQIbqaU5otWs9V2fPN0p51RhtDZRSIEtDiAbraJpqf9yI3Ut0/sieuvBDloKBlmpQBvDOqNgt7A@wrWMWog6hicXhbath2Og8MfXCAIKgwQUA6DSBQN9qcpK12LTPJTJHScprikMUesGSDTJukriArCQFzipOeEjQNqxwBheFQlQBNiWDhy@EeJQ@7wqedCmjCtRN9RHaONxWQ7CZS8MFQ4r6lRI8WwkqQQTSA7iqv1i1UJ46EpmheiYtU8D9o/jv7WF0Z/AONiPfbUYfmEURPiQwVP2YIIEQwXoipr1GPtChgoO4ZtejBzHXL5NJitoZgdJVQzeDlYBf/UmvZGqVjj99K8feg9Y9ERq1FXWNTrUMVFnQ9LPi5Ckv4/3X3behs5kua1@BQwJZcyreRJtmWbMlWmJMpmly15JNlur6xipcikxDJFspjUgWW7v9m92BfYvd9H2FeZd5irfYre@CMAJJIHSa7qmd5vq9tiZgIIBAKBQAAIRAjBbbFYFxsbRtDlRYAQjOLMYpEudu0Wu65URHCo6znFrhwkrxnJaykiua/nIHmsi9HqqW6mF3TPMWmnMAPOErySTKOkBg2yKg4vI5zQ/wr/rzi20HUmMoe5QPMQVGzwWfN4Zu1HDtKO0JoAAEacAkBaSHjRHZUzkwKvlLNvVkYJKY2MkjfNBiIriMFYBK@Lj3TPMhmvgUnhz67wPEBjN7tylMmWeOsZ/yvKv2xgPpp/pemPxXTOUvpjMZj433/Ix2NQ1hmgjvZRKj6CQMZK5l1POxd2dY5FVb2gBQ5pdSdXfeXNULbpe@FCFy2cdPsnhfMQljaIei5f84Oxb9YPOLxRLwb9UTjqP3pUlkVTh9luVv2yZuic9voIlujESSBdr9WP4t7yiDq12T/tdeIoUHBh@znSy45IB37JuHqyfuzHmYw2@pJlLEALX0HVbTQ6vc6o0fBgS@mX7XUANq0Eey4vZ7D@pSenPIknDXRv4PVPfo2aI/92mAj6oYsddpqfvb2BToR3lKoiGdYk/Z9Sz0iDUXE/WTlyQAGo0icjj0PknPXP@6ek9V3EeezAZibA1xPYQCgcDBiXQIVY0pad0C88SrxmEPq66E/fXVT9tOqFvi2/mgaQIkaghpM0BmWHM6przK1Oipn6Dr4f3wMX34Ob8eVV@CTOsjSvSOL3Vf3QSyBQxgSNh7ejgaaT3GpNoZNCxX6GXiUF7oxiiy3ZWsC0SlmrOnu@TfwR2LeY3izi7@fR/@YONMVrd@2@kIa9OhiTvDmHVah4NorNGaxH2es@ZM90dZa1t@9YF@VFaPEdqBCkxrLg6sEXOg1MBCOL7caxAXwLz8N4bIrv2aKsIokzcBpeBurz6vwu2m60om44jlqezhk4cE2L92nBxvLqbg2HoGOh15e1nkdzl29TaRoH0SVTeQ7LhMGl789nK8nSsdzDO@WMYX0@/ZA@JZqxxVeR3WpaBywvL2I79rKD7U8EYZNwG10JbqrlqMw/0pPwlHI7QYgOMnuWgqRa/ybxue/ZJt1hRrB58@kmwxu@gQg3ZtN9@H0kur2l1LlOoYrp5Uw60NTsHu/c1OMOVxielOOmu7HkbUx3Z55zWE2AJSJs6/umkCnIMBxpNj0Xony5scf6vSmZgG@8T9ebM6s0ZghUW5Il3ajDy23WL/wMVsZ1@sWG03v6BcDTaNQQhjJtw56WjheuOOU8HDhai/5CSjpBcagoJNdoOLky5pmyf/lm62zOrbM5VWczVacdAekqnUyZZqpK3Qvonpu6oBu1R3OkM5Kwdqafm8Q2/dfrh0PsVnxZ7iyXO4Favlwuk0BejpbLNY@E8nJrubzND/Fy@YAfPi@Xf6KHZGwtf10um2GBDEN65YcX@K5FON6by@Utz/@WGYWfo9jUm18u2z6lPD/KK1OESIF2k9aII7ZeXzdzNIxoYmOlMlDgmDjA8on3YQL@V6T/S@g4DiqFROxxPuDMakWVUpOGM2NIPTRtmKAlM0ZyWc/mtb0dNryyWVDNCq3x3DIMntTwxeW0MBLEkMonGvRLCEJulmdjpJyZ7I7o6NqJQ7mT0/VLEFDWB1oepx9R5uOkEo4XqMub/kqDkA68G54oPA/PKXRMdYwRzmT9GWiBqL8s39Ao9HUaF937bg/xXnc6E2GbM1mklxisI9NJh@PDOQ6j2h@kmYRTcR@g45bhTTkZlODeiWIsFfTInJPMn3XLIBjcwe/f1BynHFBLiSAkHhWPZZTZeYFlMZISWedoqjL4CAVH5tAIj5qfORbjtn7kfCJuAp4r5k1DpqxUyZIrLSapcB6e3y7CkdRuF681@IP7vuWrKXmNvRYPAJySthaRr/3v0N/7or8bhdoQYaKCWYr17Kl0Wr2@cZadwLybVDvdgUgM1LY/UzmyNSQkp9WBo5nfxGtTKj5MPkTJl0ot9Alt35DNrgluodvk2kJgQUsYXqY/fl6lj59X5xNqWiPpXuaN0pJHTRqONNximjTtZlyl4bO6GCm8vx12v7uDh@kOdjsP8LgBwwmSyygfXvTYyiUZ2yS25QtEaqmsRJDzcant5uQjiXs@urXHtvRhr7G/vbf7@iNNuk@ePPH1HD1O8MOoxV6rnccFMltx2/lgxrJlNUDANBx2Yzs@PusPR/c@9bJTskSENSkDIdVi2E@PcV/LMkeeT4xdKid5HYpqWJ@TYRCmpBJUnRBTdkfTdUQEiUbeg1ADMeot0Tvg1ZrPocEajV54DnN@TF@NBoyXGg09i6FrzIm4//fFe4WLeMgRniWu3VUmw55R1Pae@vCqeqgOX9XUzrutn9THvXfqQ3X3EJ4r3r7bfF3fUvSvtntQU5mUCR5igGJBSXTdjpoRh55eLRYfKYa81R@MRe54W758PwjP1at@M8Ix1fM4PH9xJi/5XjTakFI1Wo6OsYfZ4Ziv550R7C04SCktY6HctPgOIy4eKMp7Qmvac6x5z/utTrtDeTNY@w46UWyuvaluh3qQ5K25@h2IkoR4pGw6xHGGYYF1RcVDyo@zGwITiv0VSIwcEsC0lVeacPa/76bgYW3/zYGCu5Stvd3t@mF9b/dA7ezt0@vbj/Xdl0TP@sHhfn3zHZI445u97fpOfavKHwSBYl7Bj8mvF/HoRhTyyM5UaX7GyXd@QN1v39K73tDg1VXItzljtXzRg/TphN3O71FreT1zEUN9wQ1SPipQ3lJ1/@V7mvNV9BtOOM1RMNsfZN/FHCN3qaiec200WDZovK3r4UrTXq7k83nE@VghTFa0zl5LPH4OlAHORjytTqSyW7BRwd63ODfhsWxAU0X3CDZAGYOViuLwdsvLwXMGuUG1Nbt9@NOV2sSIUL@g6AtjarKeYYppWxkAxcWKeg/7QaV1@4H4nj6s6mpHQ8mgHtoPkkE9kg9QReuwHVGPdY6L0d4FxLNakw@/ng92@FhYPbEfNkNexT7VOEm/cZeGyoYHhauXLgcxlF0eDrQsPn5QJOb8CPDX7crAiCS0LMlEOUpk2zbKmSVh08ZRgzZ7k5DtSCVugJ1Q2B7Fyqv4eXUI46Co15HwkafdsCcmUInpDvOeegqHXRV9Wbxjwy7yVZVBnxkQIV/TeNhy21orjO5ajkpuTtUYahtJDn1sTNBuQ2BzCoE/AoYA5VIrnSbPVHzBFmD6bc3KXtwnjsS@7d/c/MTOrYtmlCqgrba8Xzu//@5rIgepdZKxU2TsqIt@j4akVvJRZrs/pDHOYpUD1UEKNs/6g1FH@tBLt4BPnHiao9yY2Ki2XyobqdpAh8kae/2eU@kJcfGcWk@IKe9SK3O8nJ1b8ZVEMCfOp0lY7O6ATnjSv4ycs7MAh0hXEbZfSBHms3Jsfo5HjInon5lEdvxNIfDx08rG9uan3N9@CRD9WMSCBB83Rof4R4yJumh48DkfGywOoXfpkWaiVsYXJyitbfC0tMQoN8BoHXjWoXXdi8a6TRNz4@nvuMYz@Z0/fv1akVI5SCYdsT4@8xLpFqgjU2XAZY6VNgFxZCchS7LeM18Chmnl9Qtc3UEvwE1UD3IE6/aJmJBahJjWnVy0SbLo0Ny6uy18X22wRYVRJMWLhNsfhZ@9zcrKhl9IDEqUQ07PiOjAQC75vmOWwvPVFLjtm8GR/L47uKc3YifTw3dB274R2nfhlluZD0umJQfW3cH@7QawMrn9IbDU9mA@YJkkp6FZTrfMGSwtWmvam2v8ZarveOwRGMy92EGxQJ3aLnp8RG1803tSwHfBJArRweF2bX9fZWV9QmVJ7mHJ0NJiELDvqbeJtW2nx8Iub5Umu1i2ypP5krJoM//dNJhnEm@OqNA6SKDpYYWFvYdDC7prkXp6ZmEVgq3vWSAayqWx@2JkUHykAX@jNSAhm3Sa08DMzGYuyuTTiV0jcE23QHRj14afLaxl7kbA6@HYBeTaBIWnuFkyu/8@iH5cNvWIggV/TGhwizRpmm9onXBAFQ8oYz6f7sEbusV0KYzsRcFeNLSD4VcxrWH/eYZiRhIlXHRhR6xr5VijJvrxklFz2CAR00AIS0@dKBbNlGBEPH957naon0x6XnoKIiUTIZBfuFxBxY@/6SmMqWHnyYpVyN2xtsTYHBksj7E7q2Gvz890H7bQa5PiYbIqkrY3VpX7x1Qls0SqJkPzmY0xiQR57fHjh7fBnmyFKZ77s7BlDpmUn6PzAa3vE5DxOObtfeLc@m5g0hMGuIF0YlpvBsxEQVJ1ZswpqbbzZOTiR7jIvhAhg/gOiCo9Wauvridwmw1dZiQXOmeZaoMzhG1DZdRMUf/bzdVBIN9a373vr08GGzLBdPAbrPLf9IdxlNzKc1zLOJ9wBz/9LRoOe5xN7jOdA4rH15huvGzHt@3E4FVahUQ@b3Nb0ta3k8TsNjB7DVwJby/mEUgeu3vrk9t7udK629Sd@uuaesDOUdupvcjsMOs7sudep3cTAiyDeV8C0wff4bsfl@kf4RAYkEQmvs3nMW38W3FjipDWfMRBu7RZqJatpcneb8fNsAdnJEH2fqyywQ9UkHdha3s7/qyd9eJ6qjwhFw96HpUKsrl8lovSN2zoAlIahPQmvjsTFm5qGEtJXK857cM@Cgdb0bXsnrHlZFgoPS2uPctw63rBKDg/enYcPGhWsoom37B3Hl8Mr1qfT/tnl23VVYNfT66b499/U@rxIzhHV6s/iPPr0lqlwO6Dnyj4TX9WZM7VCP7IjrwR2DwvEZ@VWlbJOnz9nvL5gRfNZdyQmOBS9eDccCGu2I0q50drx5Vepbh@ftQ7Xsclv9FKZbRSWvHw4QeaRUnGyMn80egYc6q76xr1LhX8wHI8YX01RPHVEPryJhx2@q@ruy9Tu3FQALAFpm29eUNdgsgvwJoNd0/yvejK09tkgQLHZqAgZRb4VlAJ1915PxnbMa0OYUa9EpA2G1/z37GfWSjmLwajPqcYT5FgLfW18zWzYK4xFXlHgbIcdYw/SdwvIDhJHg8HQ/J1LFbUuZKoayXcnfQdEEcoyeIw@ymbxZ1CIKrvch0dZ@J8FDbPgESX1OqvXEw9f67wRqwW53kXD6Yc4ZAvTBSP8YgDEPoZ8GkDqmDNPeZrHxlqPt5LeJAvvEc14nsybCCfYU0RKTD/Vl/4fhOXf04EEMIviM6V11ucWvMiRVLuDvLmArywpRf@OGbAtUrplAU0FrClvkoCnC3FmUaoVpOJvi9cgZxCK/pPtyBX4repZtj8vmRnkvA5tX6LQUvuUk7awE83KeY5xXKmmMnskGLhVmpgp4uWR28iGlZjtRV1u4S00GIhIQce@X6vrn/F1h8foc5ji7yk56bSc6n0vKQLUkmuPE3wSaaymym7@CXJ901lk2zBVF0VxcpLnnq6mSeVJMm7flPeOD/qNzpJ5g3blcKVNuF5KiHnpPw8o/cl5V6qjGVwm34k6Zq/V3XPWyxTeV@k68dvRndQxMaz2tZkgkvzvU73R5m0bArYLEvUVEqKc7RTZQZVRd/B1OKENDjs8/Ow3agkUFZKRuLwmMluPH@RzWsl40dvEg25xTg1sGaMEYdKXOcKE@6aLyxSPZx8zwHBMMFoyozcDVN4rAuPHbDIdc9UK7cgpwY4NW1yiFdwL/Ir/pjBnkbO5FucnbggmF9L4@V2c5pALHTvZWeTKS1NcF1EPupG3TCLJHWPJyHOFhK7zi6wrTOSO9htbIPfs3LCFRRGUkzR3aZoSicZSoZ953UhEr9l/l54kHkZko496EbXqoplRsi3sDKpC@6jKB7F8D/FrnHii8Ggi1NHVviu@Aq1juew@hjHLQlEZ2bPZ@qw7JH8AZ70hXQqlFd7gHwFA5EkIb44PcVlMtyA7V9BtGLHpTPKZ6q9sWxo0Jh5uCrXzCMF5xssgLudUxcJ6TkZPaB0PAibUT5DOlpM2k9Gmtru6CDBvJ@OeyNwc0ZTWjmT@ZeLTvPz1kuc5z4pFR@WHJJd6uPgYv7ho@SCFRHJJKzCceHj0qNMxjkbbsrZcA4AA/UaE/174s3oMur1okyVZgzOGJPSGkfDy6iVz2T2I3sIDLhgZZxM4h52/2LYlM0dUrpCYkbcEo4DOQ4jDsMv5mc5Lm7yWVmQwaFVctpMXX3ZaYGA5sZJu4/TYT6wgJsAoQcKnUcjIsoDX6VR4rNnjQvrLufYiCJqwM@JczZhydDrjzpN6hneycp0CZQcgySV9VoTmFB9zW6Iy8H5WQjgekxCAYOAOUq6CYeMPjT/LhyUbpg5Yw9NzxRI@vV5rNBwj4Ydkr4JgblXuJiDO3Xw4av6gTrY2zn8UN2vKXp@u7/3vr5d21abH/mMGwfl7CJYvdp7TdLFnqbLqfkefchWD6hklhMy1d2PqvbXt/u1gwO1t6/qb96@rhM0Ar9f3T2s1w4CVd/dev1um0/fCYLa3TtUr@tv6oeU7XAv4FpNsUxSTu3tqDe1/a1X9FrdrL@uH37kGnfqh7uoDKf6VfW2un9Y33r3urqv3r7bf7t3UFNoWGa7frD1ulp/U9vOU/1Up6q9r@0eqoNX1devJxq692G3tq/YSMBp5WaNsKxu0hIWNXE7t@v7ta1DNCh52iLiEYKvA3XwtrZVx0PtrzVqTnX/Y6CBHtT@5R1lokS1XX1TfUmNy3i3UIX6Zevdfg1uk0CJg3ebB4f1w3eHNfVyb2@baX1Q239f36odrKvM670DJti7g1qgEIiUqyYYRC1Kp@fNdwd1plt995DmjHdvYe/gUyd/IMIQllUqus0EhhkEWktE2tv/CKigA3dAoD68qtH3fdCUqVUFFWBRsXXoZqMKiYiHbjPVbu3l6/rL2u5WDcl7APOhflDzqcPqB8hQh0HGR2IdqvQdtxr9RHjJIzFrxnBuwN2p6juquv2@Dsx1buKAg7rmFibb1itN8zxcBDubKJ0@9gzCc3djpT396TKCF8zpHZnZezTWY9LW3naNZmTt5CqbJLyjWefphCslN41mGptIrymXNa3o5OK00em1@7hjaovJxsd5fBog0pWPqD@fMjcEmtP7K1xgcbHReF9t0EL3oNHwg7uUTKFxWwm9DX5TLl@3EfEhsPLGxk@5LHR/niLUxg/6oJMN9XAAgZxC/R/E9C08j3xVKLQiXQyX9wHYbB3FcmxyhqMUEo182RHhipIqeWeC3zuaHbigZ8Dnmw3sk8IykjP1Y/rT@5q8yOTgfCDpLNtdhQIWsYxG5/fIVCOVsEsE/qM9EnTaXGU@jqLPp17RrQ5r/vxpv9/yfN@U4bwjWgeeev4txU@i04niucnyjCwfO@vQCrFZd7MKY8@fNcmU7pf8kFvm4U9jxD@@wUZ8PmDXlKvizWq9aen9IMVhkRQo7doC1yu4k6Hzvan@tf4Bq7ni6qP1ie@v7HcZW7AXhMdcmvCOuNwx/7w6lgw0wNgXB5Gkoz1kFApOGWNvYjNfUcYzZLrqtGD5Q3P1WcTzOpGEFNmLsOvWidl42Ll2sSc5/HK/@mbz3c4OiU5g@@jp4ydr6xnrduuvgfx@RD3s0pa9jg1oHic9jZOcUbJFig@PFMfBeML@zMCFAjLCtbzpNP4IPw/WbiNtyQRBhubGiN3Vg4leNgIdsoodcNzLGH6dOTI1A3ippvpozXl4zSp@SLoS84A2ZumOudeu8Qew7fA3Q9w2SDOQZjF28kucS6sLlnvZHWMqyosbdtyDLPms4WNx42ZpwFtdbD@L27X8pnnb6cVYTBkxXrnbuSQhcW8SC2XsKnoyst@ynxG9Aczew@jLXzW/0eNH7eCO3d2F8ag6OiAy7tiS2KdONqN1o4805GOE@oBTNVPTc4Vdfl8jxWNPbydbxyDOaGBUELgGNr5pwOvWj8hklWwB@2LZV1@EU@G8A3DWNcfqd@LcWc3RUNaN/xD9brxSKIFlnZwI1a5sHRmT5aP1Y2HImSLTn6IHw/8n0mQG/Oe04iToCbUcJ4B3oiRDFVrR8pWJ0rkyBw3O6UZCTffTxwTMN7djzmzD9OnNtdyvIRLo3hmbDx/Z7WHbm0EAMDk2Ntzxa03SzkJaOr3I@ro4zkl6zfOBp/RcYaaKKbi5teOA1a7AnK3gxVe@7DU5Fb6mouqFLNxOeNTTkmliKa/ux1kB5xv/H4UHvAFiBzxz6ZlYrU5yVlGPMiMHtKslZ8JpWY9JpJZ@m3tq90A5LjJTsl@ffBlCEegN4DPdTo550ldinpv2uMgzsTpkL3hwXI5lMiYf7bLuhA0xuxHg3G/xZgjCooyuMEF0BTq76kugKe8@G4qgksTqMPEzCHHr54m0PK1eWex5ZxIcarF/1xOv@ZHsapkceXHwoTF0r8vn1ZtwTCh379ZsYbHCg4N@ANtFVCbbEro8QsA0@/0hqY4h2k04Bp2xn1cf9KZD1Isvhtp/Ic1nnaHekTBKP1UDtUlW7zzNiLN6Ri3ujHBboZVn/uAmnUewEBX3JNe5NeUR8xoe3TCbjp3rlZLynicpz4km7JaUifhcramvXyWXEFS7DI2Ygp3YLi7YZpPrwbmDHX5X/eFnzP1QgXqtqGU9kzogeS9QOqneYx@PzZE0fdCPeUeDugI7IJYSJdlIs4aqNEc/0eyk7ZqyiXdM@C7llnx/PZZJjbUUVZQwrq6dmG8tR50JKq1q16DWWWhp9TGjMmvB9W3uYoy9haaPrVX2U8@KlLIoEZX7RnXEk8hN@/QRT3qTv3I/xuihLzjj1iooEIbOinPVaTnH@MGm4EMnGrbcPVHSZFrhANtvvPTp95gXzdahdvvXDEdxNKYVQLPQuS4wjIb3l/5Zr7HV74annX4npHUaPM1fi8TD45gf0WGnw/5VzNGNJIymk6k1Tp7Fv4y4YcO7PZdcd1xzxaNo4LlmCqPhuHombiJ45xxGgElAXebvwaSPNFvm0eOkUCZ9/5Tt8Ur@@tyyD0uzCsuJPgBoAbcxYUEhd0hHfDHJuXy6PpXh5KYMDo4nKqdCf47FXgrjZ0QiPoZJYWyQmTJLcBuBldlcjI9a10GLfRAO4Wgp2o4QiSf2@HMQIqg5SZEfYSlQVqWnRaeonKJcww8hHsbzyb365J@MPSHwJ9AvPZzFLbMYgUVc23hbimW9or2MEi5sHthhGc2SmKRY57TTc64fcpyL60mo6eTxPGqw5Q8pRdrN3hRXYkR6tPBBED6vQSKnMfYxqSyrZZ/9dkAFqY684nyGjW6zn@XBj0Nc2TmDYNrSkD0H6XmkahKVENt5wrzWRVl8Kt8@YlZX79prEwSszDI5c8KXe1mjufANlI7MrzjW6g9JGGcnqKdNPZbjUX@wfEfqzZUdMz2zzaJ10/dvNQQWZqvQZPmgxaStjPE4Xs9M4jPBNGmKsaUZ8RCWr/xs2XySiNeVBsZbpTG@hQ7zaJbYTdlJxfZ3S8Y@JsVLWPSaicYOKcYdTkrX7fejBjW8MV@CaJiyvGqwxGhAZDTG8uiAmiCTpdLdKcTcp3GfoEeLKId6W0Q7t3/mEnXSSM64PDVJKSeXoCcct@PSJsmlQRvGF3ATJxquFVJW4bwOxnyUV8qdwMkwEgQgtOIol@xDyQ5u0lkTfMTRAdpeA9ZCJUgietpwLRys039LMPbKrzd3tMVDY5wrHa8LpGsLiVYVnOsmSOa@Ob0eNa4ZyhQpaIjPIIVt0ZRsOrt7q/5sWygfQZDSnKwtfYsBGuOrFcKG/rhJjWvowElVumRqRKUHQoNFA40FWqWcdiNZrkL76wyF42HdoIcRLSDks4efFV0C7rzXipbaKHLdGiOLr8kto81XuQ0pkjCUvIP8eiiKqssLVwIQCcZUvlIiCHBrytjjUIBd77icl0JU9xEVrJQwLOkje0VN7DxnpIOoOsOjx06O4qwcz1wYuZlASLGYnSdBhHSW2VkSKDTRzcTFyfFkdnuSHKQQG94XilNX6F5J09D2nBCQA2EX/USiHJVUUNQczImPHvupRMvfnPqs6KQWJ1OJPhbDo1xpMvVpMZWaqnZ1NV00VZLo4bu1phKJFL6LsJUKf@4/vpriujy3NqHOIiOlZWj7bAQqp1Umrdvyv8bqOV/KNjqGgefeDDfLr4aEWEk5Zb/ZAbta5iMD@G7/0601lqkGEx0rgP3SmcsuniwIWWPNYqpHs7DSNZ72rIMCs6btt9X7w52dlNvXk7ExNDqPho@LxSKY@MR1fm9sq7GV1OkX0rkL7YtutzC4@svw/UmBZX8UcUiAsllBR9QlNCjifH94KpEhgANlRe6cvsiKtf5Fu@2GYMAJJTqPuk1yam8IiiegjjV6eX/IG0AMUk@wv6CBaN8vyo6@q1AUTQ3FHENRaZgEX2bN6RmRBx/asM@2J1UMDILZWDPRvOVXNr5gBkFkE@4sdl/sf0nMk7Ovom63H6gPiI8MTwEL3yYL7Oy4BYqSBSeMfLv3ImZ/tIGKLjtd514xsri8DnBmYjJxJoxfePjG349Oa9cDL3v0c5amFWryCpq5Av/UgcqeZn3tLP4OYIUPCe075T4PB16T6TSZmaZ6PYKTJ8LoYSmYufZJZfF5T0zT7PbcIOpsdPPsrIGa7rMuYHzZc/dyS@Zkt8TNfroutUHDosDQOMHnyt1K4KrZP08sXo7a7btJRQ4DIB37XRJRIqH8OYHIZwA8AvXwI3rCi/ZPORrWOxMORUTBQbCOabmDAg0UyGTuNyu/XXnValUtDVZWVLW6SQ@5nKpuVtU2Pmxuqm1638T7D5XVx4/XReZu@1/o46b5@E1tEgze4Vxpng236ZXSKrg3BmttdPFSobIUrC81Ks831uPCUXUT1/rp6d//63//9//2PwpV/fK/8LLJL0c/20z5fL6w1Pyy9MO3dbwfbR8vL50cLQ2Ol0/XwWV/Z6/h/fooFybmo/nhSWZRZgHnK9uRmnU2e5/RRZWJ5XceDj@TdCmrxWZcWNRfY4kcxTJ2sRk53yPcozyhJbwJOjC5lCckFgnoGNvx1DvNCAZ4NN8QJQkX2IFKeTlbMRv3cAdjM9hTlUXtiYd11ssId1oSTwq4i0szVq7Ti6MedsAvWeeV5mUyIf12Rg3Nv4Wf38Snm/1r9eCTpx4U1YNAPchm@ae09oy@@kuFDm7nSjZaDmSzAaUkRwswM1RxhxU9Xj9wrJ0JcmcySxyyB5CMmwrOLLfgArv648syEnAtPs0sINqnki0SPmRCkcUvS71v1C1fKMe3bOqqDSsKDb2K4cqcExXbv1CBwlgMAZKaz4Ug5T5ViZM@vpGMp4L5ovs6w9GEGDDIuv9yh8c9PtBctNTTNs@ptRTCHLH5vHzF3Lgul6EZbaRI/QkCfKAiy8ki3yRcXlzOiJW300puptzCdtunmU9sHcbRyNimS6G/KYcJxJrbJdxST99r0Ybccryish17vOJUlZ20/VYZp8j5RXfUGejrClw7BtQXW9s3GUnoUQYkcMRnf3l6hPFGgfEUNdEtEixrrFp9NF1GQk9fTacO9vNycuQQofCzR2P768TY9gt8S8Swg/AAI2VN@dphpxtrrytDJvZpODxBdMCwzQHVRnJuxvt5iNo6gXG/bZHOM2Q2OU/GMzVlcTAMT8/DQC3u9g@H4bhO0xZpPqNm3qcWwgUTkMDg01XPap5BWFqku4QpYpvClkMIXtAd6/Bo0rdZe@cEXWqGgna7gkGQYiemZPQ11VcTdEy4@js6wUV5Snjb00gtYlnywtJIQ8q612Z4mE0NnYypwR07duBkM4KqHZmGF3ShC0y053zwS5K8Cx8Buu6svgWoryKsPUP9mJ1Oo16YmpwG3Yy56F9YVzIvYjxzKEqxRspoKE9KScQ7YEV65M9pLxAyNxl3RpkFz1v4FOtwbovuPMJOvq0tfiFUHRuAjgOY8c0Q9a7XEWE5MUMlMTDyqs6W/wSh3Q1PCb/xVTgGK35a9H68V/CPfv7UO37gfep9/fS7z5hokWxm2Zxa1IfZRmLpsUIzYyFIvRqrtNi4GvzUS2f41FNyh8UhASFS8I5@Lhx/LRBCnxZ9/0Hh06IQJNVlwKRwc30FgC9MobmYxqKwmFnwH/im870fS76iuZV/0YfywZdfwsIsKnmbntY5wzaB4nu6v13IlZO48HS1@Gi19IhWQqfRdW4YXWC@zcUXJ9E1qRIxlrM09Xz6PcUNKUJ8u47Ddfp4Te2UsCZy9yTWl5S0CNXDnOvJWLaiMnnhCcpPVGZ3qbji4ts8IQ4fseAPFLGcycu@oMR00OE@D/Nn3D9HPWEMuTZ5O0Q4ElYGYiPCW6g5QDbBV@ZxqG@GyzLfc8qrLfhuZSDUvYVFZ7bo9Xs5raz5@eV1KNG4NdN9WnxanByjU0M0NUKXtDK1fE@VNn588m//c@@3xdHixmrhw5B@R4u/La49XZRHeqC3h@btcnFj8TmyrX1bHBdoDUyPT/7tf1P5jb8QHKSMn9OfjccG1tp4cSNX4SJfFzfW6KG0ukr1/p9//Vdqw5Ks2BCLdakRKEZs3VBkK@wx71K6qqOVsixdTsQKX8wCDLEwpLU5vcAw6nr1aZG36Ra1VcVlpD1fGXsUPcWzYdaITYVkJ8PYU5BmJAUqqCAnII0JRVs5thvGbAPMm6CpfrmfX4tpBfCLNuewVVrTjfsxTIaWZFlEHehJjbSel4eN4o9Za95RzhqbknWjQmJpp2Xt04frxA5v@9Go00xbSZjhet4Mr6KTPPgwH7UuaE3Vi7v9X4eFS2LJ89Lq00Ibm/sFtuMuDBhSbjDO/06KoA4GRAtDNjoN1JB6oH8OF14BRwsihX7HnkmZeJKkZQ@ipuxhpWMSUxa54xfI8TCak09UaY//kgKPyJk6EKQTK@1Tj0ru7ZdVdsVmlHy85vWBzVs2jtUuMHJiDTtg2ZTPcBuwO2jak68OT/kSEpeC13XJkg9brUao07zMQtaESgsyC2dRd1DJtsW9O3yn4sRE01/UzLlQch3sIORyLOgA6zwahbREr2T5C9bjSQ1wk6LPWq2ruISsbZ1Xr@pbFY66ckPVV1L1FfUotISkHsszjjc25WYT2VLBVuUwauBIbWbFVFtsgjYP8/wDDGLplnob1xJ0c/gGJFEtaY62KnO7LeC1MPHIVSR39mRrUSJXZxaTy4@BySE3qKE7od68VEYCAl5wy7BQpvcDuQFRMWFGO72M@PObSDb@PTQYbsMeXIm6buvE@ahMS71LxL7pjPgupSISaL@yrg12RmYPC9q62LIhaLPYeMn6YKl2mRdbnNF0R5nDQBuXUNms7FMdNZUNL9vW0WslUAR9yBZLqw8fPV578vQZopwt6NbOBoNCeawCBmchwWCN2qNFNr5XKtnlrHxCCOrpKgF9FlgcwMGs68r3jdvnK/9epVTUwIpZhnXFYTSkuN6uZJAJxGGUx4xAaxRvmPW8H8tHaNjxp5b/lf4Rfxv/gMxwxh1tKKR3@uFt4pkqcy4OByosmNkpjvcQHlR8neLmjfrtfXibiGDrKmxPFb2GB4jR2bB/cXrmckdeu7Y6pAFDBGe/1FhBvYxGiYMxByvoonrDoe7cvqgYeEfTLYBRLqYE6HwCnIaZ9lsZaktTjI5lmoTgWRM3VnGE6JiOuuzM3Nnrq9ru9iRii24YOoabdy1bSbljT2ZwIINYvU5zD4m62tsFXyXVMilIeVVmAVdEvhJfhw9xV7qJQNQOVYysZr1h5N1ElhLzYuLaNClK/Qi8ZsAsFW8npbnXaloBghhBqHeTrBAL7HmOS7IEJ7eTMU7By9myYyP6phPH7GBOV5b1tUUpZ@KoAguZOQCxb1PMSkOKZfQoP9Y48LL0NoI5yq1obA1oM2S7Uo1m5uQwE2x1G4sDbEQdN7RA@@u7W4HartGfnQ/bARTlzepPaLcN8Twf35LGt1RW9R3TBa63WLa5hc3Ub7iiRMxS1A5jEwQhfNsSFTFKvAbU6jua9jKoj1Jj@zjhCrBrqJVwszuqBwkcvfAeyIJevFtXHHxdh7@VZfNqWtJYlyp6WMgW180D26HJQlKrhSSkvAOI1UkQ1lFLwu0LCcOLBTpr3qFeuxjGru/M5ukUy8qCitT2nQKRPc2zcylzE1usarZYLaMfb@IL5tsbeeMkavf1XTTLHLfwxr0/xhu5uzNH7v8L5qj9c7jjoeaOh2XIHuEO6zacb3RyGPb@DI45GfMc3Gh1TjvYH2o7r2hEMXAAsMADhrhDSomlIto2R5wob3bCyuR8BCOh1ce4GPCHGv9IN/5RGTKXH7ej/1cbn/sHN/6xbvzjMuaaGT2vVTvH3fo/psWJSuilP8zsXqi7ks3/oy1d0y1dK2M2ndHN/@ktzf0HtfSJbumTMjwmyIGDuK@/mZtFE6kebNXriblFPqOddnmIYz@bK32svVqVLC0e2t2L@KwCbV39YfyfavyfQhrxE8LQ4SzC2obatbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RnfbqCStZj@gJSoQ0b2wN9UKFFPJAEpPTpnyiPybS104@d8VZZLsOlomDc2cBLSvCkp8McdF8dZDM1TU7r2yzD2S1dbj/euW/CBnOw8/6Fhohj669irpdM5O4S7BD63VKN8ZpDmAf6DVHilU0ORnZkb7tbdllYb5UY8cWE/Pi7EWCHLXh/I/WUufQN5yo3NgyItrkdXmzqoJprlleyBdqu2Sa3WTd4j/Epc80lz4rq329MJhHqlBv@GleTNZpq48f3zQHSKk8fjAAiwHlv2FU/V8)

[es manual](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/manpage.html)
[rc manual](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/rc)

rc/es code:

```bash
x=echo 403;$x||echo 350;exit#;
```

rc tries to execute command `403` with `x` set to `echo` (as other shells), but es just sets `x` to `echo 403`.
In all shells (including rc/es) program return code of 0 means true. `$x` is empty in rc and all other shells except es.
I don't understand why rc prints 350 in this case.

`No such file or directory` error is fatal in es, so line 25 now uses `[`.

Answer (score 3):

## 408. [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 17220 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{   #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\';    `"<<rc #"`;    a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;  #{IO.puts 295# ['];   print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';  #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^0 ::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._e#8g= ma  cep:s:
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({1776f005-c9ce-4658-b045-3b468517ad67}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKr4xJtvipRUKumWbtdDLaluXV@SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElsaK7Z7fXbXtmPT1tR7vt8W33rGfb64kY78TMuL1jz0TY@3HCMZ/8A8qPjQ3Hhvsf9J6TCYCgREp12/aGY0ECyOfJzJOZJ8/Jx0Fb9wY//WkML3LkWLO@5YzJ2PDGpOua54YrkgczsqObXk7VOA5D7br9ydCwx16ZixGFEEu3@xO9b5CeaY0NN0M8wyBtw3IuwF8lZGtiTzyjWwObRohtXJBDu2N2AQIZO2eGbb41XPDLEvLQsK6GV2PScYZD3e56ZOSa9pj65gg50sHSm3TOiN72xq7eGZuODV55Qp7blj5sd3VCg49cg0UqEADVOaNxln2KhDxxXM@AFJyO4XkOOpbAUXdN5/Hu04@vhVdk8rEOmRpZxvRa8opCXpiG270eQyWfnh4cXHfVyFcFxyYHN7OkZMnuZOwcjq/Dz5HdvmHrRBVLonrdMw/IHBtWUS7K170KUJ/G2OwspQMeB6YLtav7tUg6ug21hXWZIsZwNJ4RgdW/bllh3XpE98jEm@gWDWdPhm3DDQJ6Y90dm3afXJjjARkPTC@MR0N7I71jCF3DMofm2OgSy4RITs@HAqDtLjkzZheOC1Xuw3RsawYRjY7ZMzFKkA8AiFdiPDAYnKE@g0q2x9A4iE48yIZlBNCSXAzCPzTakz5xJuPRZEwgb13T09sWAG3PSNfo6RNrnCFt8AMkU/eLgWH7jRnAiQDi1GG5ej2hWTMWbV7vdokM7RjycWYQE7BGs1UmmgbuxHEBaxAqyJEPjLZrVkZjCnUGVdRzyiQny@C/H7pgbnXLc/zMLGcNPW3oq7TOEO6R6/RdfQjY6BoUp58eHhGv47hggxvDsv50G5iOPiZbWyS@//RhnNTCahHdNhdWUZVcQhXEAk9yrlsTaCHRmnCgftwwNodVFt@Il0kc0KLKJJslWei2RaLmAEmKXAID9H9VU@DOE7VIsgr0oBzR1EI8g2n1XL1vWgaD1EdIBWz8EESFp5wlmlJkIfuO1WPBOjTBAtGKJF8ghRwpwLNESiqkiOCzRCnl4M7DDdBKkB0Fbg0yJ6sM2KL9Q3vFNrdHevrQtGZ@CjSJDskppABQId8KQFeLAAXemoa3BjfN2vIVhT0eANYH@jmAFyzzDKmSERImrEoJXlIqJVHKiKSXJe8NMHlAISAvVyQFSD4P2MhCFgDDahGSz8msIN7AsCw/2sDDaDS3BRluyHkBcFGEWpABnzIitAA32IHuqUDgVKBmKhAoFYiKqoJZwyQgXB788lCl@SxLZqB7Z5AQS0ft0goAyg5gFMQ4EjMFkQQQoMYIoBqqOwsNQsMGkdMI5B/yUsgToGdFhRSzpFgggM@STKB@FMgXthYF6KgC@VEQGLQBBRqBAnlSANsKAFW0HOEiyFY09Ie4GsQF1ChZiJMFM1Sckscb4kHrUCBJBdJU1dKiMULe1ByUN6fRVqrmoXYL4Ad4UyGvKjQpFXKrFsEf4xYBh0VsxNB0GSJ0xAPUCjZ7aIuAjBzkh8KFsGBWCxrDn26NBnobqTaL2e5h1Dx2hzyiEaLKWDx4ZxGbkBUZwGBPgOyr0AI02mvgnQ2TtxQAUkfwRtekhNoygYYpIYYKGdogX@uj8QJtSp7maDQbD0I3lbk5QEBNIIJGX@/MQk/ogZnQc@Ga19BVpTR3AUjOoqsHFNaZeNYCSGjIqjQp49y0Fm5F6tY19G7P9AbvFnnN0kTahj62zbNFKrlcJoJUPeKRR48lp4IWDTs2BRi2@gM0LcqiFjDMyAkraCnLikKz1zZ6E7tvCKViJH/UZzxxxzDALNIsMWfX7PdhbF7AUTK0mHTAXDjnaA4tTRtzoSNiF9N0TRjG75POABiL0LPE4JdKCxiaijBmehtHdwG4MRgNSjh@9cwpad/v0NFjkUGN4qkzMEdB4PLawJHKpYlMi/lI26CYe1uUQ/KMV1N87Zh2Ik7iSW7OwZjDOMzoiA0D2wscrXD8xaYL46tDuYcF@UzYwQiZBKQtD/Yw@lpARqFSOjqOxDguGXRcDeCYY5FAIsAOGs45sq90cFxKxqMDaNtFbhW4na7hugTDAovrZehQ603anvFmgvzUIl89GLsNGOJ7ummFGaDjiD6mjAC84x6kN1vOds91hnSwGeJQajnOaA3bAgP3BQJ65FwYi6wvxnV9NLKAewJ3gzFvkJkLnfLdlEmPpsoyBJEwHlQ4AKRJAddhukaH4t4vOsTWgD9ZzmKZqLX7GkJ5EGGrNOgswHJ4GMeeWFYZ@B2jQ7Sa1DXOJXRhrNcyy4V5CJgxYKl8EG0deGbMOc1FCOm@KlI27zSoWc8ZLheNja@HYdEHJjJI1oU@g9rrwdBqTPUhcPYE2WfouWQILYbVINYEyC5YrEPSdez4OIRy4QIzC4UOS0IZZsTJ2BwaIAU5EAVrPEszjaM7zVl7Bk2ZYisrUrGH5eQaokTuOqKYQzbiwDoLsH3dSQexhmmbNm1BwCp5yOu7QCqZGzd2SaOhw@0CXzfyJT0RDRjwBLMWERQ81tt9DrxDISKvatgeiBeeSEyUw6Dl950eNLYLE8oOBAuiLmB3KBIQBaHTVOyIHEU5NqDhmUVM0hmNCLjDoATN80AuAivqvDbJW/C0BiBKdCauOyPTEdSEOYRQ447T60HrfWuMBgCCDLukM@tA94RKxtbDdR1KYDqj5WIubJsGhLFRONk7@nnSNwDtwLj2UErFJr8owGhEi0BRoduMqbV1wBQWoTOaUbRwsUWMnuOI6N51DI82Fsc9C7s@JuYZfdo1oJ/1FsRoiEw6tFKbChddoDx@90L4mCC3sjCYlN8KPjZs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE53SQ@E7QgLi/KG3ukYo7HfThxKzkw7wvc/O0C@n7oKPjDRG3CbO2TrWquBoGHLifCyKAdh1ke@OKIjrfUleoEyHqHoySiLNbuRPIQ4v5Y6/wrDLOXgFb8mDyPaJVAIokRiMkZSgtTR7AyQFo6R2lB@G3qbO7lZfHCLJu8OidAL08bcKEB2OFEKnTAf62EIcFs3AYkjC2HVlhww6JLDHaB1b7gCshNm0upGXUVJF4Eo3gV06NjOCqiAzBAuBln2oXVBG@MJUg3dChsj7S7eUh0hwV5MMuFABmPoaOS40DMY0ZnRGQVaZZHW5QviiXCsSIrkwfLQCkNGHAf8MY6CEGFk6dAWsIthTwXJSgdKAUSMCcpA8xyWYiTDtNdTWH7@LijpZ40JxlLbNlA4090ZAwLFg@EZEpoR03WBDJ7jIMHGoGAwEWk7hTFB73aRsiI6aL@/nriILXpv0jan16XxDjqKrz3uXHdJDwVxF5gO6ESJeM@LJyvUncaMePGSMxpLNCp78hCQBhKhyhM9kO1hkDgAQnMyszsJfqmL8RnCT8a9Ip8EA0ZkPBr5BESF67lD8QEbzfAM@jW1VUgfhm9BgKeAbjQn6CGJ6KG7wGdAJwQps1TqtnVyBdTDJcJ0j4kigUiiiNkwLcPuhmn5iMC8RMsrsiQ8t0MNQmRUwxJgcFpyOkgsIfADMUEj8uAgSf7Yig6U22N@lK9hjhObzseRBGNFkuQyZH5hAEjQzJjAfJgdc9zy2ZX79wPGZaNahcYG3BSQzW4yKtEGE5ciUGoILFJuxE9EHDsnY@wbiSSUFwPPWW6AbYKWWq2Ry/HAhR5H7XMOAgFaORtbcoBYv56fmmeT7vWKttERA/HY64BpMjtjvsLB4M96Q/U2rMaXsApSbxyxio0X41PQNxovdcUK5f1gruEh@1v1sxKp4QTmwG@rK1HEovpuiwa9N@tYPkvATNDZGTVqQ/bP/AmtkBBlfJ4g6LQ3eioDgt2BwSFHu6ePqn5fZJ5S27TLSw6W09Et6ryJwfkg7uPDB8e7xz/fWgHDMtvl6w6SmS3mcaidTIW@PZGyolrejMJYAH7Yuh02RlwOw3O@NxGcaYRVmnVgcJkG6Hx2/NXrKAFOCNFBUwAz3tdYGhYGmC6urXuDa4Mw6afTkGQYJQhLhEMSwAwNmHX014P8HE3evsXKu56pke@OObMmOgMQOEqHdhBPRM9rDFjg1e6xEZHGBS7UtHHBYWGKhgzy8zFyzdczQ1npSJP5@NnB/nGVgvXn1QQaRPLGwEvpbleENm9NQARfFQbIH5g6JC0uMo78NM3rSgR3OksIXtQtWQMfAKCsIzpEsIZB0bwB5H3vetmoq9AJWwC1UwjX@cooP9T5shmN5AOHuA6KvKtGUeqxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx1cjmjkC1Fh63OIs1uFChdHIBxIOAbXfA68wR0ERdcpM9W@9k/eXwj4x5lIkEUEIKceRYRaVqexaH0Ipgk7kl7IKE5liG@oBSPJ3xSkuLB@oDY8ajwGQm/PzXHCTnJ3koSwkLqu7uH6sMgsD9lTWcyqNCAsjiOTG4P1/k6HrQR27GcvkNSEIdxh0GCwDatLeZu37Fv1JCOjljUGC4VAv3FiRt9BGON@ZYKjjRWVFxli4667V0AlVbyGiKJYoiCkmh48bV@rgO6FuU@Ofx8HwYRJSfLoVmmF6AgEoeiC02diCt1IAIkJPr5WVnAcNnwRm8PPITIuh0W2id0YcTdhfdKR0oxRWll@JVZ@sS5gfHXzuxa0wIX1rTAEEHZ4dOjx4dP95/sftYYq7nckj0rl/KAOEivDbyQOGB4w96aYl0Ti4XgYtA3XOxeQAUmIKAEq0YTzwXCLWIQkWVgTathC66JT5yBHfeS1wtzgb7Ca7vDmtAT7HwsqB8RBO2uhcKIy1atcTzH9jMYj0deWZKglw8mbRGEVul1x7H0vkTjwcBgWZKCosvhM5zX8FbFgMx4M4PFYJNbwDrM6Ayibg0dEF7o2jeSBpJg4OmslWX2ByAL4wK54SbFsAXT0khdkBBAVpbCslECTG2AW/8d1BPPmvZHilpk7VqR1azEB8GWuj@E3egZIDolYLQCVCSvWUnjfuM@mQGVRkjXgcSImKKTHB7BscAiwEjSWVOU8wPkUGqB86VIKyiO3kxwNheolJSTswUln5NALAMxDXhWAefchKE@7gyEsSMAPMHp0XmDSCvseR3d7okp3xBkFvi@e1BUrf6y0bCbwKA37tO84fpzfdasK81khdyMkvLDJyvQepeKh203cIC2S43QNOmbrKFnXf0mOevqtHd1iTQejvwxRxiRJ7vASL11gF53jWjfwwhS1FNKLYWVMPA7acWEkIVROXwgpiToUDDSQtOTMF8CML3IHkLLAboViUAWsxkhwzQbD4B@aCSxR03JmxwuOms@1VjOCk4Ki6MZkDwaCIm2oGGGAg@a4IhBwKzEQQRCjgf94ywLbKtJhJSh3I9dz3TiHl2mQdYKJ2y9EdQjne/u4EDh4RTlGAbosPPhQAHtC8cJcmHEcSpf99iEKUTytxsE8UFcDCHQhYFwUtwON1hAO6Sx6AwBEC9o2jhzO1hMdOK8AzR2SJDmCec/gImx6QJGHwoJkVlBdllBWErUZblIZ7ZzYSO0tkGKQtscs/UGZ@LisrvZjZYNgmsqCwPQaOEiQwtdn28bHTbRyyLTUoAcqpOhMXRwNgMYPEqNDFoEna3tozjq4aQ59GxZwEVLgC@QnT0gpB2DTVkJQ5TjoFXvk/jYlXaFzyVdeAsd6hb2DgsfqWK/0k8DBCzvtKATNf4kLGWQnCEN9IJO@aDng4Dj9psWtixerzojw74udjKhNJGs0B0R8Thbh7qMb2xsxMvxWjwDpm0wbaFpG01pMG1Tk0BNGE5EE42RoSb0rdMY6NaMz@sB5GmyiW1giszLW3OU0OvlstbM6HXFf6v4TkJVAOYhtIAvgBNPVqtoTCb52gUuG4EIESn7Hradk45rjnwUfAI8CbNHuxfvdy/XqKB4fDtGhlUX5FYDudyEG2/U5UazcdnophvzeAZjJyt6FURUoJ/jxFDsu85kBLxjPVsWgLwm61q5WWlX43I8lUgUBQsS0pPJe8VkWme4TsQNaFOJRiMOKPWxU@8MXApvmlGTyRBRkI@eCYKOZSXi4mUR0m8nm8l0HOIm4xkYGarxOOCFrnl6tNA4KcEa0YE5BVRCx4RRNrqsQWk0XR/D7vq5MRrM3GiAcOIPGH2cxF9sm8HdRTiQRAn1WxY/ylMuTTYErDcLB/w1zh8iyzaasQGGYzltSEubtIKh/1zoDZ2xLn0qgtwmRkbs@EZcEgQYjKkPg0SL/cT0sAvrtuFMvOhk58o5WEwdXE8HEyCWwU65DLQqc8QZnYFD4ps7AJ2ES05I@HH1TGBrcAGAbkeEG4koMka4XgMMDt3bZAJdpLvC6MSQQjPBSE@wPJDLj96IYWoVGofImJDZtx3XEAAlEIOjG7no9kCuFiyNH9LJtxvDj@9LR1UcykwDKOKB5egUt4xcR5akRsNIfLuPUY6NLmcB/egBeRRZXbhGV0pxdKHYcQcwQkBpkBKrYW0NfQ/J8UZdcTyFqFwCx/yoJxMwge@9IF1VVfOdXK8c@GGrAGQPoJJQMLZByg68BAU8k34l77OZqWCa4Omzh/ts@oaO9zjC41Rea@h0J8Da@qLbsWH3M2Qf2pNpO0MT0BDEf3tmHTvOmE00gGXd5BCT283hxNLptNP1maFb43WctmPR2ajboi7CT1xPt3Q2Dxb47n76BMSN56cnVbEcCSTp58Nb08ap0NXJMnweRpc96ZJvsELlsYbJb@Z4HLeCDahIZnyPPHpM/O2nUEeBewHdgy6Fyzi@exHdh7j1FNh1fyKDWkNHP2CJBsTtqLj3zne8VOQ5uq8VA8NwCg3HeNdFbi8Vlbqfj3u9JWeNOp8JSJqshXOWOrNtqUtiajRLORYI96guhYkCytMw4VbVteEKNBzbYCOGi5tPwn0QA8MKVjePgWPBFTwY9C3kq0BuQimBbSc1gMkf4UINJd24/Ec6wAd7N7hY6GwjgYXmYhu0A8HgJiFLw21KxJ9@r9AuZDv@sqnHyKrjZtjMzlaNLbSjWOcyiVJiCwObLQCxVasEe/7WBcOU4vEwGIVK8wYxaDHp3oIbRQ13inh0vp@jUSqcJ4FEM1VloTEt7Dev4pJH0dAjfKMxvSern4FohBs3N@9LfaNCt1mtwVcl8In7PGx7RgTg@DAUmzvvDIDOkPR0GZVQPxO751hdgS3UQYMhTMTDCvL3SYQbSv19w4bpBntJ6WZeFhXpa2Qb6g2416q0djNAZONqCAi6zyW5OsucX5E6DHnnojeyzHGTzMWx0xr4m7Xs61tcGQ/quvrM4/xtNlWye/zxp3W5ySBwQx0X34qsFqfBTmlgnIFRwi3tYMLNQmNzTDkBuhnCxPIqImRqStdpIPsAgyVQIWFCfokw61fG1aIsPQOE5YSBOfdmwwwxknOxZ@njsWGzNsdWQNejmy1V@clUafLb/rpHmch0cQg4UxP9IIsVcnL6cP/4WISW6yXi@7iIVIbuqHcGwKCsK3SAyWjhy@ReN07uYZwkzhxw0NVA@mj58aFRV6DRg/wBqSPt6BtuAhyTuP7TAWe65EYjMg7NRxBu@eqMKY5CYAkjCWWiwMor8//cZqKWn88ytPg0xSSgO3G/DLg1k@LENt@IHgw0lG@FIL6wCuNFdTNBqdimkvT39A1x9RokLMo0QgnqdSK8BSoHgXnSbFbYNgQIiwKY20fs8jytCrqhvqoEVV8FZ2BpKAQ/evUdeVmXhVIzvbkKFN3f5u@FZ@WPwEUIy6A9Y2Wymwna3290ZJYHthzJKPdzKk5fOwhSJpvMwLNpbxo82LNFiQ7d4rW8VWt5Ixh0MiQldDYICxKQhJh/UsFvs9SfUn6QeTAadUgkyWWIdBVRTq6uKA7JpkooDsGkEFYZ80D6BML02IHSPPZPKUS5A9pb/b0s2GcbHB@IWcuLxejDWHjp/Bp3Kpzz0XiMOzTtM4cuOYWmliwqOeQIw9jDM@tmTNwHSx9LQcM8sLDqutx5w3aPPlYEoCsv/po@daBz@j4vDEykLh3TF53eX5Hy8j6WpWT9HbJ0pAUzEd7cEVIoFWngXrttrgsKSMCtacF7RTAgUtieVTErKsGxB5yKgfEICBeTXhZFv74Fiizh3d/K67//29e7gP@btTOAgQInP0NDC4ZurCmht7ay/KhooY/VFcvm6CeWqVPEUNNdIDu6C0XSrdCwGjTdByAIMPwPcVXDr3Fom/gArvGWZsZyzhYlg/fqRFat69lAMjvrwl7bEsaSoitQINh1KRIYE2QaNBIlXawSjClbBYqI2EjG7s5UsG@L0MbM6n0wGU/YExjXOyvRHOF9W9/0Q8o5va0YEts8f0uVu/rZpOsIo7N@yKfmV4RdlJ4uQwvADvgr0i00ri4@KyDbjB681wVbDG3SBX3d1So8e@KNhDaVwrvMRjvC8JYUXIs91wUx/XOEoWE91kyLPj6wJfrQoaH4GzIk3O4qRJBmXkOzpbdnyIMMvnwrCzc3AMWpdtJpWVuzuj0arY@PkiSNXyqtjj0VOwwfq@YIJLalVmCzaLTA/ibbO2oVhitzqFuC2o0Y1xLzVXsjbgQNl1VpHDz/QQ@B3NrIcUDqTCzdXZhuaeKLfATLCOtmpP1h48jsOMAOjIhSEBU1GDoiAwYlmcHuvEVCuKOZPiI7MMxVaAxOtAihaTUJcDpj3LW6pk19AEFju0VxT26kkYjOOkx1nAu817IPAxBN2XP1iPZ2Za4@gDgJVsfSYRxfOxwsTQ7i5OMdDfXC9Az6WI3Ys5UZHXesle7LXSCY9otO493VrD3TcjxyQp@3IajvAhbYc3WDjuLS1G2BToZHzbfQoGCbxaJCdavvWPliX9LhsbbWJ24P6b7//lAKF1IoRbmDQgXsj2Mr/nstXT@T3LO7KoiemXRxi23EeMsQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2YFcpDFFiU31rUkYl1wu9Fnw/hmGjnWoDYaO0Yyy08DdYYRSEQxjl7HYP0tq2dtT634YUboBtnBXISKVe2YZMFjR540qJaqsfMkYiix/OInqWRNjYqwUNJ61Xxt4wv8WIePDMyX7xdj0Z@pxcQBPx4Sh3vqS4QflGsdptN1KTHTL7Bh3szLLRG0E3PcIRecjMByh4WaMvj0ZLdXqknRmH9@OssEo6NJOdyl36PNl6VDxDk5piT/3DHrfKjExCQ/3qFVzsiz7DExkxWXJcpskpYVxX5vsuZQwdVmkvAiLq2xuxLg6DYqW6C7ItSRIXSfY08ClkmSbtjGe4fMDqWnbcawvU1NAVPHMsgPSqkB3@95WYzfYHf8cC1lMXXg44dHurZu0YKONL1sCflBovq3So0tCH1SbAi56DnFBatl6@/RNZIHprlTwfC3OCbH9v9Z6XtKfDVHEoli4tdcxDtVpG5bOXtN89jZ4JVG7Fd4y0fAXa3Fxly3pLpbiY9eI0mgGyDK7IKUMjKFBrbdw@XoXtXX4r7WBpg7e67ynhtGRpvtGZ12AkQl0wcbn0hpyhFkaOzbIV2PcaohyioWbWX3XdRQ4WPVbieTDod43mPqY2yjlYsICd9MwsW5hXD11UWY7aDoQbaEXZH2TgE51Zsy84L0S4JNZB@p1Mrx7uu1a5@/gHOgH9PZ1u2hvDrH2wBnYA2PAtq6HtnWdA9rjmKn7uS3rkOv@AHfTjUZLu@yj@LQcy/oQfCJpZITScXor87SP52/x8NiXgssO@/uvOyfv9DGjHWhY22sGxgTGJc8ZOyNDoLZ1QS2c6GHPdTQ0WKT@WWeQbpXzASPB@2eFf6ds2ded8WhEX62RNfHog0YV6LHpu/imHtuaQvdlOm5ffOsM26LvKPr7VugS@GoS0zbHnQGeW2ct2@g77c7AvCvTvq4MKZjyYdYPkl0RMyYRHqKzaJmAXncmYnupRv1P8HW4rtL92SM2rIWGW/iVVTN09GS4MNLPOh6bDUUTKeOEcKQ3svPjZXoCv/xmYo4XQCN7mcLpXbYsgYZ1efd3T6zlrOgxjQUZ9ndVrG2llElHhlwwZGB4lHXJLu9zi3QxTWOPdRmKlpLmKLIv5cug29/7Q2cHzci8Lbgvta@lTUsrBzl7MOl7Nwkmm67vAouGj/XTFnQ7dWTKGsYs3fZf69CsWhKes4R3C3iuiXHrmkru1kUVGk6xBN0x4dWCF1TdZO0cmmWOPPYkQm/tUpy/lwlk8evrhQw3s9XCtF8xXaPHlkDQdBeLOHRc3IkMPIjQwZV0nEFHYs4YL0a4bKcPRF2wyCJwEHYd27Jym9Dq6g/HTOGzp0Zfx73Wj80xbtZc0Spok121vehO2F@b6J75tQmUbF1jQ6URbBnSjWoXQNsKeE/0vtl5tFQRYSZ9BPs7Pdlrqfmj0826uBiYHu5oCg23TExhk2ONGFtdC@SGFSGvz9uH@jIWHYidxFwZetXcujOa4YG1GTXdNq1ujuksq/9eJzqu2wR2ayYuJsPRxPNfq/NA90xFZ6GHZ9TduzABuPAGSCsZ6NZ49Ux1ZMoVuDB/UFwY13Hjn5uW0yefF2UCTBswYcicr2g4D2B4PsINOa69oiXStD9w2RMnOgSXFewN1K2B5ypsc3z7bM54jJtzgjcWho0ceEJBeoxPcefLQhBOV2Pk8d28/uJ09B3jO7S8E2fidgw0hipPomKBn6qxF@w@xhMdDqpsuYhKaR3Hgu4FBmtll@k49mQsuBP71lEhf@uoUEaFV5FmQBJf23/yPBltDXS39l1caKASbWFau2HgWiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLPGQqWo6pluF74izi/qkOpRcP3RWyTtHMxhAPlhgAuI/GT40OrhseGfaT50nju3AaDQCQjk8NpjagaWNHqsjYrTHeLAe8NO9M5kTCnbNIMS4DX1ktKF@rYXpQ8YiBvihPtbXDEV0bpDKf6HpzrZiWm3DfU0n/SLmdSLtcoYeGVMqW6xvMKwPCuNOh7HEOB@31EeWVmy8kePY7EmprQwv5cntVAWGAvr48IVyETfiL80LrJTPlov67JztEjG6TC/GurK6Rtux2POWPUm2yfYE6K5peNJjVLNA3fJZIgD35d1KQwq30pCFaASc7Lnu0UX61aLGAqQy/RJbgAa623FwJcw33LI7J6Ib4Q4yHe7tZxsH2oD4KVAsvTPx9ZXelS1r2B7Sx1qBIVKbx0YbTwW1qUKRsT69WZlsZsjXphDZ0RXqIAjIFXbqPEkcgTSSvHvYWpKjlrFqjuiDUuq1y@V0s45gm0bnrY6zZg7F12Jueskfyiw9pcY1c9WRbkRnkSWdHrZf2ZOWt64BQ2MZwnjggswvjW@b3g40vaxYD5kMDVxkXl6FWcu6Ot6AFtZZvZ4eElfXEHx1g0BLQtWDjD8Udtdyngge/s8efCLBINzKZwPtJ0C67l7Bh8xPXNt/fUgLPHK8cc@cPoN84ymAdeQEi5WDKPBiPQNNqXWFgNqzJxabfehH9l0Nu1QcE6hCaEGwKLkeG4JhnwtUF930ZokcduhL2kUFwmOjK/iqGHClQXgcnP8Kg/nvFQuoUdqImz0ViSF2ms/62z9XIfcioAzAbzljYeTRtzTyjg4fPzsVR56ycnzaHeDpiBt83JJuB7UoR6akXutuZL2TbUfrmt5YenCiCHuPD0UMsAbfbEVDgBeuzC291s57BopkJX2tFIS@xng1g/jo9Mnj9OKIJknsDVxnaCSj3nsnJxk8afLJyUrvaOwD6B09Z7o2@uG@oiRXNN/nNl0dXEc9V6S0DtKpAdIoNMZHTDXMncxVxxkZ3dPZyPgUBk@k4N4HJp9fW8in@rnZx15ISmsRRTsqKYn5bDKyMxuEbcMN3@vq88wcIbXs0JfEXmu3oyDnoEmutpp7uG3F/zoXQ2R/J8KXi6TIN1trVJWxpHt/14wpirIOzyd6D@qV5NZW1nKAVevDlnP@AUvJhi@8CKGTMIZWJZh37iMvCEMg3RI@cHredwRje@02mNsAhM75lR3@wrBnui3Qtazb2IsyxMZNbbcG@dz4gAWpcIfPOepLX7nGF26pJ4kONSbvSPjUjUTZ23tweFeEYx@Xt4f6@OlzcqR7qAfl9oDRHBsfkOMFZ/RawHkrVMK3djm16wIo9VZ4/dHq/lwmJ7rbdezZ9O5FOHoGFYd2qt84hIU2GsiwzKm5aqzqsHmto9XbjO5Kmx3icGZLfHBUP44P6P23/oWiyDLVfoRvRWbWO2om6OAkgSZ9hir1ol6nhyFp6CDfIoJDcqU0@tiY4nYUNhu8SqhfOb7lbxn7Csn1w8ltfsVb/LK3pHfDDx2JJsrKLQBzt/iRnBh6P3asi4Ej7umu4a3Yf7wyQ7cVpHRLQUoR6uwrbKcLi755PYuPRxf818rWemqM3exo4LTN7Moy7PZQzyV5gvrab/r72yl0l25v6Tv@kQ9mX53excRYmdAT/e1qD0ppzlZ6ARE0BhN6JOKm9/ICaRt4XsPum0zFI3ngjPep7RbBLDzxvHovgjl6OBmtzzHQRvwqxnVyvhTwBcjMzoVHHuDRuAWbvkL2x/1xq93X8bQknBhETaePTneD1vXsRFIjKS5y8dnRkjMeHh0/O4m4ucZ0uk7oFabrZMiVPotUn55ml5Ldqr08X4Gs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBjNh9cnKTJKD4NhgPrcDnE91ezJguVVjXGdOThis9j2ZTuo1yZU0P2C62VX5uZ4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe1GqhOqZWa12rPDU@o2sPwAaRMWNLGFBf8ZIxzQ6CHNIoazuqc7ZgfpayezIamPZ0pddwXRy6izTx2lvdDXbJieVckMehVqF15EFdDVw/N@x1xGnVYUWhpN3OhWnXWKp19cI@oOK/1lXJg3WM2jWagRsibqMmGP@4Ix0Elk/V5J3hPzkJgt8dds9ycP6@a06GdwemYNPpuwO6t5C/6wDNu4Ph90bOBo5r3x00aE7l8gPjAzOx8cEhh7OO8wF5aPd6dwfa95y7Az2ZWGMTZZbVQZ86Ews1CKzy23f7K91rW7VGQyyL6zxRobs3cJPr/XFfpDPxQAYyQ@IZRhRem@Mlx6DNRN1Qv7xhi7aTvAb3E4d8FTXJr0DF2w@so08O1oVbXrCZ4BI/PRG8MK7b1DuaaXd28rdmn1o@pNPZ5vDWsAuVf4euYzNbct3wuFD/tyKlR7pl3knQgg0P6h1bH3BAY/7kXLubagGDcLC@zj6dTRfi5nLpLaZ0YpXfngpI6Xc6yeAjSLg1XdEik35s/5nhrZ/2o6P/1/aHescLGho6se0FwQKyt44TiM4gLA/oJ08f7J6@OHp805fpM4DhMPo5Di/jazNj@j@Y1gVPDL6ZkkjY0GuSyx@oi6qQQKX1iU1U2rxJ1UVA2KsrsuGraAAPPlD64CulQN2upj0xUKsE@2zVuLoJyVSrSq5EtvGLcGWiyDRN/NhlianQDBKrk81LX@FCuazMyUaV8GWe@CovQo34TKs7AEZ91FAoIpwpZHMMPpuBugZCP1BErgidZRY6qPYXbKIUVVxT8RVaQJ42L48Oj/ZPTndPn5/U5ebcV3gRlMK2IbVArc49rctD4X28gfTKvvFAFa1YkBz9eBLOTntBuQh@kG25aNWloi0KxW9jnM1L25YkqvNDEuaQP4FnqVFf5MHAicEOSkwryFf3UmbqN6gWEagjBpqnaUKllYm8KuGRDpLYpu37X/9@IfXF71yW8UuXmLCvlh9aYt9xun6KnkHuvoIUD3YPHz8/3idBBhet5sLsjgfVUo59tYHpIYJ66pl0E3SVxP0ocairajV@EAfExMU4KVMtLfSLCdDQIViAHdTv4sdOkcQmhQ8YjIeVIv23r0vzuIjneZIQNh5kKg7JQpunDWVjY4OcQiMhD48PP90/Jpj//YfUGVGEIMgpqoj40x912TeHAhVuwTc@3SEVm6gKLC6qJibQnbJQ74I4p313tP5Ln/QbP1SJSvhxofDraBxHvz0F7faCKoC9ppkzSZXlsS@T@opTg4RoEwq@U4JLx6gEFQmy6ZmowgXz0EOdpMuNHXebUlXAItnFz5jix1J1@gEsyPrEHjO9f772rxi0NDGkORmySTPLPpfFRwLGtzagsbcNkKiJZ5swpo/L5DW0RFyeLTMVP4JQi9@IEoAuU5OAUlgk4A0lpp7UcKX3v/LPpH6FgHkM5m/75qn8AGy/5Nt6YP5lZn4pYUO7qfR0kZdohlBXsl8ClpEQ/4j7yNdbbaZWaYE41M0aEFZiDqGazinWMThLgT0FoMcLOIn6p1Bp0Nygxnx1Siw9w20mUFlzWZKwSeEsj0hZE2PKdpZfU9qcz@WzigSZFM4DgPQrK31UmcEAJpNl6CbcuTmqvmpDU9vaIjxO9RrVfIXVrLRpv9T4V2FGNyEsB6wAZK5OIA5EWcQAv5ofDUaftJLEqEi94kocCVfXgWGJ@uPwhXbbRwRPEoAshiMDP9sxxQ/9jkEA8pWPt/HTuJEvcG36gAQFxiRqSvKcr4joqTOG5gOddPGNPaaICE9WsCEQVep67PPXVOc3tkfxZs9a6M8IPvXl9zURaQADpcnXR9No3fIvEMQJgijzq5pv/SVpjBt2U2Jtk0Az/cGKxmyD@Rel/po2y8q9e1PdcuK6smREFtk5sR2c0z6AwpCEKqmapOSTiyJlsyuL5JfITwaKgzrdriA5IFNAMjqG@doZebt7@4efPDs6uaFSmIaMXw8GdL@2lW4IYqbeDA3xaLGWq@TBgXTy5MFBUBGLTOcj1BgIv18S5baSLJaqEOTi6OP1oq3K4fXSrc/xC6Yc5Xp@NfW2rNFIN/KhyF8iXXr8SDigh4ivJ64WV2Erl7stSwt4UgT0HtMAcSOrieTlvN4EgdKOxW@2hBUd4WVMTGEnAFPDS21K2NhvFg4LFn6Y/hQ/9elF@6K2ui/ymxpqrEQFNGPnbKHT03eIeETKGyQDJJITpSDo2t73jDHpC82zKtB/zB8dGaKK/CIZzsu3YTwCihYVeBwXqchCb7avMnoAwp5ltrlAgSJTHR1ouA21RjPlh4kk538AiiWcYKd6yLQ8Fele40QSqR2FlSG3aaEO4CU56NDI3R1NQOg8ckbsgyB0T9lDIzAdO0B@H07YHLRBPpkMIVyPvo4Nur4PlFuAyIDJeJhVxksBlfCVUE/TqOYb0qujKmq/4OKwm0tMk@LAmHbNPtD2RDIDFO2eojRJqKgaC00VU9txntbZohZu7Yofo16PKNq/lLby6SIDel0XTbtrTBPxi3iy3IT00T1@8eI8nuRXtSWqNd1XI969rj49zH5BuZ2S6GO/dwa6yVdRi1LpJpUAt@uAmRrP4GuEpZI48Dj6ddkqcu4nY/cxGIGNSPSG@ogkJjZTgSoSak00EnaG6oYUaky9sk3SaSpQwYt6iITG7FETG78Tuj0jCamKHyAGV8/u4uutOSJ1RRSbYKaJJMkmfiV0DzguVAqc5EAIhihlCraKTQjEDMgR6yQia@AQB/0hLLyoItkV3vSjiXQZ1EGc0FKT2n0S@errMufIl0plv0KXqWKJQOu7SQ5FCcDeoHMBXw/Y9bWjAc5A/BW52IKQ36R4MZpujGXkka9WDbITi6hED7StEYC1UFjeGbh4J/Zt6CvAH5TLz08PWsWkxJNQPVvfNbu4TM8@LBKKeP6n4KCbSktB4xUm0X2M0VARbovpf0N9rAe0w/DXSGosigZfmXggLHuLtqkot7Z6P6JfCxAyiwOAf4y9FYBD5cXBdNcKv9XE/qc/jSGzkdhUlLOWe56O5@QKPJRKjuTIvc2GIGzW5erOpg5S1PjNtAEyuZTKnhsPB73uYV9q8DzRSFaSUpeXl/GD1JH5MkfyQtdU82@ms7mW195M55pSfHM2UvJ18c20yRermbNmo94kR0efvWu9S/LT89kbnjQSIGvuPeOVLB8rl8jldl6LnZXw8@gg3pyRt3Cd9Qj@qfltN2LW0dzugQgb50ms0QCMK3yBl6R6vAl/Ku6/gosJ/vWaWBO3m@/eJeu6Pp7OiGmaI6/bhdsZAAepJk8IyMv3gdKzCBJp0DeVoODKDadA7HaNfn@yr8/MycF4RyyIRVGNzC5sPfn8hX9VXjx/Tshz8vz52@M1cxHNdDohCHVqnl7zK7f0XAw/cP6nP96YZy6PWlt/@o2hZGzg6xm@vj1/guYTJXdvY@PegwfZbEZVVWY@@vzo53d3d7MPM7mjem47K8gbW3/yxxsbqrqlShtNz1Oa8frZ2We8Kmd58U9/GG8dHX3N82ra//n1dzUFHwV4nJMC0Am4NKKAEZ9FuBXksT70ir2NQStXYjP6a8UC98sNotS2C//9u8/exMaxmiq9cOE9jr2J5YsxZgQD2LTAdh6rxbYwWH4em0nVahWMhf/@7yB@7ROAgz6zLXjUcgGs/CxWE6o0ylWslgeDoqqQ7v/99a9HcsjIRJWyccG1Q@pw8dmCym834UrRa4tDtbeCLElBOHs8GBsOUYr3lftoMcECL9vA74cY40ZMKWbJsx0IeVxPp9NNsSXAJb6kk0SSoqgNRbkP5EC4l6pWhRRhin01LXcfP06QpFNafQdGTOP@i6Ur9uLv5VoJpvL3APiYi@U3dl49rNWgdFpNS9XS9PK7FO1dhSLvODs8yZBXcRBG6s1XpPIYvWq8XFT5TCaz02JdY4pYE6ZBF4nhxZ6xWOiCnZdcc6thv2@S0J3FIjfjkijoleFi@3j92X/4s@/92Xfp73v0/s@oIdjumj0pBYHOoXPU4Noplzu1Gl9z@csG2mvQouRysVyUWvNGIlWvNY@JIn98Fc9p8ROC44CCaTSSjTqNX6PJ1vzk0V6LLZxrzKUWdfM9WGDqAG8fUyS2jDVqDrFGyLVwMMj6ZymE@nmtKSBrVBXqSj7XFFis@g5UDq8WSnyrGRM2Z0B31GZNzanPyE6NXWSw6REHc6Op@aAgfn5ri7ItfBa2WtQpVgui1RZhvmw4P08lLlavS02Djgy1IKM7G@WNYjlfVqVWbf1VWcTAiwY1DOPIi53HwqtC/HYY4DMWtsyI28toTYTVQoIGTJbi3hEO6gpIBPQM9o9eangRWl1aXuErvklt8aQC7UPVBLXf4mWFDzsbneiHawN@9A9XaMXnBnXxnWmQm9cGKSspVZNy9/L7Kg60d1zRfHMwYJBOu91@22kD@6Hrbb2jK2N9ok/1mT5uT9rT9rgz6RDWZ8ii9K7m5JyiE1hFIabllM3YfSySppbUIn5cUisWtZKqFRStkNcKslrMacWSVshqhQIA1AqqViplVVXLF7R8UcvntXwJ3FUIk4cwGkIo5LSSxsXe1TfIMSNrTZIOrkb6zuu5KLZ8IzU4eAuCM41xsX@Aq6aoCknB0CfDA/g9agRxHH@KwpEY8HCXzXep@rsU9PhaeotS22ZN8HMJL7G100wL83kdzJWK/9@qhcYKvZgJCtecp9NbL2vA2rys1dMA8qUPUhQIBSq2aqS5Rb3C1PzkfP@tJnBHQnqrvlV19ugt0j4nNAHk1lI2d3bSIph2IGZtE/p2Mp3eFIQNHHDr/rADgZu1dFAegNRMkHjWieedHQKF/xlvECKBfsy35rV5fWs@39qC/xZ9zv03uM63bvzpa3GtCbPwbyLtadSlWkNq@PSnCXZRqqGLKDXAUIM3hKtrarGJIx7yL2LzH@dfzCyeoQtmuSlCrrlYiqRiqAFXi6W42Kv3X/xveDfef/F7yIsS@BllLnaJlEJKoSRbYgItPIj9xCZP2GWDGe/Aii7oUHuCjjZ72LjYJUmvRFJm6wkJpZhPijikt5xeC5XqiOQVBF0irUhFCa8W83wrrcxUEtvi8wVKQn/uxhWPx//JK7VUiLNJINQK88rzvCeRXC7yCYErqqwIylWNffiEfaPq51Zd/@Tn1l1c7KpEjDLgJ0EYYrgYtKOYJAlCjYvVtoZ4bAiXYQSUeM@rnwnPdwWcotHHdJGtw6Yfqof71VKphvKPsXlE@07qYQqeCvz3N6AUpNGDoI1etTME3rrR03JqAz@SERPab/D3@C3@yGkHf8dv8EdO3@LveIw/8qSNv9M3@Ntt4@90iL8Hb/D35C3@nvfx1/iKpikVfvOSIiatlJT55pSnCKrAiFVrfGXszsr0i2@8uq2CwOpPYiW0bCkZa3zFmHaM0bjszzbiGS6jM67o1VKlXVX9oP4GdPQRTQ938@MylD@5WFZJEqdBtVLOcQXcLQkPcEhrJcVx4z/5zje@Ea9W40KcfqwrC25CGwO1aSCwQswsywl@BBnyB9XtefHKTvwrdTrBkCs16@jZBA8uViWbyqYiW3JHVtpKGwwmkV0iD@SB0lWoICYbRJ7JMyIPHaULJgN@MphMuUfkPpFt2YZg4AumcUseo6kHrz78egDIhZ@JG/HbitwhkJCFrCj9LrHSwpjyVavB1Umc8K8MkKRFRZTFvNnET6nV@VevGlKqqZaKRMRmLbbqrxrxJt/g8fMaailL2jNjo/GKB4ZD5lnzRxcS8zwQzysxqdGQGOIBXbQm5/NWa//pw1ZLwpGwQYxaeicNBH5npwoE339tx2qV7UaZjhfBmBGTtrYbNU1Acz4No4GKbukveS0gwru2QUvefHXxCgSaxAWKNRfn8LoIDC8a8GgxgYd6SxcvGhErNUjSxQULvQLCkmHByET/IA/@Q/3Nf1z/J89JkiTqzWTicr6VoFcSf8nk5fxy7j9ryUTCtyS24IcOYMcol/MaGmmgSzDVE8lmcj5nbvBMJLcYwBoks1WjcRfhLpHzDdOk6bJH4u/3DWn7V4N9hesVv7XldkiMf0Wt@mKzT6MxleUkkCf/gz@4dK1f0R0VyQr92utmu640/@SH9KNO20kaKJetVJQUYRY1q1Yq2cBWKFYqxcCymUiUbl41eVvJgyyUzSaTlQpYtgOwMlghbp28S5MqacCzef8@S6SoXl0FMLVsPi3jJqtKJUgpB8kant5htBqwfHn4jH4RCWhELkaQFOB0CKUDCZl@Uw2peJwv8/fvJ7oGHtXobu8m799XS/LVVegyGoGTsuTUanVNt9VCd@3qim/xdItOKQd2uXh1pciltBInScdNPMUvvkJaCUEh99QaTbYEJFrNFsDbz0FuayufrdXyWXDJFyEiFIsRaMhxnI9X@NglLYhSLDD6xVfQGcoIHRrGR@9yHqO1SbK5ZAKIXxI4x3kMfy7SSTY@5XLJSlaWY5dzngVWSiUWOkmy@UQxXfJ/1Y0kqQF3xH7I4mnpbKqQ2gFmGX/edNWFpLRyaVSVefXSKONU/7wCI7znAG@DOoWM@/e1EiCnKFcanE9/qzACIYMFjwYXj6fJvfscKlpy4@XKDq1VpZgjsXiFOQpxoOOkCNiV1FROKSIyOLOHGsKASeCYoLZBNjiVvvHBlRgvtYGOIPjcoHxcFy7SJW3Sx4v0UY4kJrHoRSzC/Omz0wkDOezyfUMrjUtFzcDFCC82va7lNNZCYeg9ery7t3@aUbcEElMPdvcy6snzBzEFrbmFnXpraD/e33347DlEOHq8v3uy//Hhp/vPj8DdIxeLKxwWgsEhHCQiphX2C/KCe@2@1Q1DNyaG0bqYTC7ekNem2TKhLq0JFMrpu8QzWlCWkb4oVwXujunpr1/r7ohe5P0PvvX@B//D@9/@zvvf/tb73/7eT7743rfg/hHc32Hv7/zbUg6fP/niX/zO@9/6bXD8z3D/Idw//skXv/51dlP7H8H9XyNuf@TfkXDs5gDWL/3ki@/@8Cdf/PL34f5X/v39m/ev/Hj1/b1vrr8x3nd/5/Yw3/l3cP8ugxWE/c5vMTd83wj/WyzcL3///a/9e/b/E/@Hxt9@/2t/hA/f8s@//yf/9f03/qOqFv/k37z/5nfff/Mb77/57fff/Kfq@1//N4ocffzO@@/9/l/@we/@5R/8z/T/I/r83Q/5v//@P//z//3P/9Of/4F//xjufw@mH//5f4R@@je//wP8f/f3/@YPf4D///Vf/83v/@rf/NL/Qg2/wQz/z7/6t@z5V7/yX/76N7/9lz/@@l//6o//@jd@/y//j1/@v379v/zV//h7f/XPvoGOv/Hjv/zDX/qLb3zrL775L//iG1@seX7r1ucXH@D@xT@Ay4fn80PgfEi5vqzLFz9Tfv4u2FikAu0EWvcvvv/1X4AG/muEvP/Wj/AwLtxr/j9SFRrmR8z2/wODerPM6CODCe5fff@t7yCK/idAEfxDfH07tCz5MMu3FxZA62@uiPSLP/niX/6Q2mJGuUZXknDoLqrFdArEm1Sp5A/f/iITRPmFZWghAD@lbyOFWvL7NtK29z/4@vsf/tP3P/iN9z/4JRy8hWwps5sRlDtW6CBg7gPCYcD8h4TDgJ9B@q00naET0p@BbeOzXFGzbbvy2Wefca0rCU9971yRz@BHPgsuwrzwVLjvFfihOx4TJ@Bef/Wqicu6ETdJYcAllb19L9x1DykJ6r30tqSozMu4kjZZLFIBB62oNSJZl3q9VBl@BB7lcuoyI2w3gPejUeecERRJ8aFuSETRM1pK0yGglGXhSNnekbPpQkrXQY5NI9w05YFSAUeW08g07Sc59Zd@0R0CTVPUOCVsPn9KvafclK4Qw79ASJFohNjsX@FImrJL9MKv4wZGavDjBavL1MjlIJn0YrWAsoiEcWkp5kLXzGm62RLBEkyn6SnI3mCAFNLg9QCkgGo1jRGrLItgZYWpFQnNSjpdhXJjbBYn0yoiiOkDCgViVtPHpJWqTlnENMKrBehIc@h0zCsqny5WH0KC1elDgrAQOAX76lW1VqxOawjuHcNOepp@QPOEwKrpae0d2KsUJsTjYg/fQVaK1XS6VsQEsZCsejItVkk5Wjha9jRJ@3UAbzz6sL1DyD1eKfJsoWQDEcZC4zO9CI0BITj4N9Ipvzj0HxjpnaII36BJ@akQ5r9NeeRtxjZjAIArCKIoErhxL8I22QHvKQOVpsnCK80gpGmLoC0gdCA4m5Tm0rR@09QC6YPzhWuODaKq2QqIGxWCTm6Hw@8K093tMrc5xa2Vl8RnkeUKoVOSc06HMFlZ4y6vdP@EwqZO5uCU5zAESzP1pS/MLCJrc3OTi9V4jX8m0qqRJOKelek5E9x6iYJTmfD5Eo/OBj10E5QV4lewfOT9138Yy8qFGLcZxzXMOGEpkHtpdu/spMg9wCd9L9w4IqQ1J@vEGLitdJpXIaGak@ZephBtsTQFdMWJ0ypdM01zmQwhYjWGfuTZs2d@bqjDyyqXhv6kagraceluMpnEIIYoZsRMxn@L9E0dRN8gUl//LW4iRklUblNAnkfHd@/eQV3THWzlQ5Chib@ZTc0WqSc4MFVeljULzmSp2RLHphmIks8SkqC1CleS4OGjBDTPJMdOPrAmElyJuFoESRhDAtbFRCrY3ZhXkK6wU170ZDfJFZaskJuoFWcM2bQ0rtKHx6tY/hLFXDLw3HtG9p49ebL/9HTUbBIOv@s7GRutket0DM9LoN/u04esCaqlfDJWryNWTssq0jluvyxjU0wfPjw@PCkThiW/ghK0HBW6wO3jpaRwsdHoxVbM3wzG48dZHf4En@UFKhJqCWhwMlbjYh0DBStocviHu8I98foPnClJyBmezyh5FHSTuFAL@fh5Z0JQdTjTMwZdG4/OiFtbFANc7VKIrAuhQ40cqxwzCAo1EK1UDAwFZlAKeQzANlwSjaud7J8C6NNnRFFlkat9RqYiZk2YczWrahl2fzzYxJ2LfEPmI6XfrMsZ/KmaBk8lm88ouUJzY8O6FDChBm0Pl7gFdQ7WSwEL/BFchPuIIx@BE1zCnHC4sZT48@yHzyr@1krU55lg@yt5JQcdN8nhWoEPjxtFL6BEsWuLbVxs4/PPx6RW23/6UDg8wAmD6YAE@wsFsysORNomuhPXoL59QrrmpyZ@olfsmt7I0mfQCwEhsfl83gNIhwdEranUymJ08TnvUJc2mOdTnQOi2eNi94OJEa5wv1yuvlOyBchQufxOU1UOHLiUhBsaN6D10N0gKYn9Kh4kqmlFKcXFFJ6Hl6ZpHG37hCsbHKGbf97J1argk9isQvf@cPgZKH1aXazi@2Gn9xZhNZmFRR/wIP2xS@TAr8D8fFtAlSHXuN8R965zFZ8YyPfvazgDpGXlsJiEIoHMocI2tayGlQBu4NqMZQv@6hTP880YZxlj0q2COdaAR4X1QyXGE7QhndKKMherx6BXcvVmvfr//a9Z55rTf7x/QEu9XuWmQNyit@@MYeibLP047onzbPF/9mwYtd76Hz5znjxzhg78Yah6gpSnsvhXKkvW2/8@0UPiUoGxiBvjmScZflk5x/2jv6Bn0ybN1kW3fI3jNbprt66Uss196DJ10twKlJHXIPQWO0dNUAtclccCS2PTP1td8wyrJ@Jxvyq/Nappsspv@Z89qQURa91q1@lMcH9VpSuatm24eGqbRchm@YpjowLharD4CGNN8pLrVy@oZhnOqPZF1Enn2rrFdcW2052J3nhm4cE5y3GrcZB64oHHAroB7DDO/G5rWrYMRRJHzmibU3OFdF2Rgb3AWylm1MyGsV0olLtixzJ0dztXzhUzXTyT5y8Nb@fkcl/87MnjR@Px6NigB/W2syWIgFpcUd/idrGcy0GL5fl0nSbTrMtNkQ06wsYGkGlD7wrwxpVjT1CLTYjcNd1qNR7f1hRVUMqaXJxzC8QBzgdKLStntyR4g4gm4Yo0DIiAU0SysiWNsPrACEF0MLbBmNuS2mA0wVjakkwwTmqaIm9JE1aLiLMah5lJI64yWJOZgXLpjxRl27GNOVfO6BnzkqK23Ov15qnL9MLC6ZcCswHS54KeaV@G1ooQCVcmk4xgLjzBRe9BHV76C@1lXs0V@Uq9srAX8nylOed2hkbX1PHQX0O@vBkrD@M3gxqDhBqEm5ddxxmX20bPcY1FQE3JBwFZhm4GyPLzMLmGjCle3kwuHwk0vbwJJZvj52GsIFvcfA6VyfANve3lSy6WOv5Uq9WgYVxmC2o2l82pWj6fK6jAc5Sy@VwRKlXOyzlVhV6YLRVLhTn0Akl6F6Pf6iV7l0HvKNOvFSX0MlO3XW@S5LunpnVZ1ATWjxPJCgxjsXdc7N7xp2qttn7WIgE82qeqUKtquRKYNDSpGh30VFVQNUFTBEXD/x0GFf8fHl6Fv4pPiKWp3Ckq4XsKrBNwhjZ5jMq8xg45dfBzjn3ywOisCbE30OmZhD3X8by/Q5gHun3GvB6aTPN96PVIx2/aekNzPFgT4vloiPr7DPcfDML@sA0ZROrJAjyAh2s5zqoABfL8aE0pn4TfmgFksI/NQPDjw48fnUbep/u7e4@4PHnw7OnDa6@cHyhHHu8fnIbWAvMNouZCED@///jxdav/yj57ftybOC7e3MGz59nFI3TCI@9cFq7lQKEzBeI/0ErlEGAhyQaIYYFB4fCg1P1sidz3jbn8wiij8QU7z2964cEdptqhzJ0Gh/x1qkmkbZAOU9OIc0xUhbIvKSqFEseNiO1ckIJMuo5l6S5xer0NcBzoeGDZQPnHsrAlYtIXjmt1L8yusQE8DaRRAjGyRzPBPQIgw0mHagAC7hUV8sMgaBNcvG1bE4NMRmStI7zQCY2u2R/AkH3hBAG4tq4TuL/sBfGN6DW@3WHM0qBuN3ysm8G5GFeK8fwezz/Sx3rFNQovZVIuH7kwdHt9o7Y/heYKnUd3Z5liRuPHOf6AlO2XKbWPa4CWM0Jx1RvVUxPgzTc2QOb@q9/80d/@8a9uqw15T8bZyyePs@oM@AtFqrSr70D6H7avai/JdtbZIQR5eRT9xJYRK/arIC0TAvJtGeqfUEGIoKBDqCzjyzsiFZvVUjFXLGlqMVMsFbM5JZ/LZRQ1oxSKhRLAk5Wiki/mSkqmmC0Bl5MtgW8O5FcmLUmBeCSlygDW7liTrrFFJW9xACI2W94nbxN6ksT00D4hvAFxeA5nRcZUW0TKrMJYShSZaAUCEHXSIbGDgz354IDnH6AF9zbtyTzfRUuuKMuFBzxvUJ@9InJsvMPiFFEvMj9mFll@AJUyYQDwk0I8P0DLfh5nq3neRMve7sEBptNDi4rxIdgZ82EWK7AUIJiNFpDhKIA3ITQItsvSydKM7qMFk0SfA@azB348/3GQHfQ5ZsEYgEdBSXd3ef6QWXZ30WePFjvHMvpVtOzSi@ddsEBf4fk@GPou9FKeb4MRewzPd8DUmengNgQTfnXGHus8P2PoQQTx/JSG1jtnPN8K3DGZT/3c5BC7ZWpRWKl3qKWEP55Xg0xjMC20aDyfDS1ZKNujR5/qg3HX6LNr5rJ3B0r66JGmm9PJ/kH744/b/X7bne3uf3yMXnt7j4AxmU3cdr/tR2y34HIg1t4jVT8bzq5fUOrDVqusWyu9vtpqZXX7mldr1jIwhxDrDeTMv/qY0LC1B157j1o7@qpNGhRgC4nFEN5tvB4M4f1AbzOv4KJe9D1tt/kKNn9JaiQ4lEdwvwV2xzMgvnZmqHdcp4L2aZXIGeRxZvW83KxQDzIEuUKuzNG/l8CnjjOPyctZfVqVm9VpteDviuwl@MZUzZl8ZmO4rZRy5Q19W1Gz6WkZFdY4vTiJC8o2SSj3U29J4mlyWwUZY4NvbG8LfF1pbucLL5EclfGxrSrFclZWSZJZtUIZ4shxmRB8JOuF5nYhV15ELhTSuqSWCwXg4wA/Y@AG2jj91yKJxIWhnyWTmHU6xQTloQUnM1pos9JLTDPTKsskmSUr06pSYZ9eIPI1aIlEF7/zM@mgenfCgPYB4HRbLuMOnwSvlIo85EGSEkkgQvP5nCHnMgvCyuWld3nZmIekUQLTYh7vxddOz05PP6OcZM2fFjtyDaRxFd/68aM98fBZYMNP94gHyOE6rriHtG3Jh7G6gdMpyC3iIxibQaoM3PD4sOtY4j7d8gpscuARaA8UfTX64umjJTgnA@eCpYzaVypUF7PdMQh@2cjsEr1aA5PeJQmaK6InLyhX0KrVqq3qkCoogSIGsb5K6Gd/FmAOPZb3UCcMjX6JR2p9j1ZVnsO4NI1NAU6rSgTl1dDpvlLTnUoXP2j0oPoAI1da8G5XjKrhuo7Lg0jIV3rbdnVie3rPODJc1HZ0@GwTeBQ8Z5voESO5SRr7GHoPRZu5UHOJvcjZ08kwoQu1dnLZCWeHQwdETuJrQaEv6dHvVpXn55VelSReQtA3YHc3SaIrPkhuZyuApweklQQn@VXvVY@oJJ@tUAkmgbCgw1H8YLn1ZLX2VWCtGOgzGPMhN35FnwFUTAwAQx1QHz05MueVTtUiCYFMkxRH2Uq/WsfoV/jYEoABEIT6VZOrCcILrgadujKL6VVv0qafwiNyW1HlfGUKbkohWxlA7eovpxW3Opq4RsUCqz9TzA656xXAKaAOwLy9Srz/ha8nt4RclblVKKgr5B5aYqs6rdioXBvaRVWrgke6npUzuSIwFrlCBhgDNZ9R8hktk80IBXQFriCTy4AjSE7AtCSsBE8In5GnsqhkFEPJJORXZvdVMnOWQG6IIi2ZGTv79mRI0AWqCtsmtcNbT6bVFKCm6xB9S6BNFUhJBcsFOB@QkZkZUEjHhm6xCEmBaKmEtZnAQJunk9F@vVku709HXwOvhPBmO58uyOm3yWQlsZGsesYbrlbhakh2aKlHG9Bw/Ul04k2GdahkMCkFtVyvt7GIBTmjyRqUzmxd9bf4Gt/MyBt5BapoTuegFMLIRnQSGdmihduohRy9ZUDVKSW1wol0QlcrqkJJyqVyMptVZjG5kU/2EJMk0eADhQ6JeLygxuMLqTcZr@Dq2Qa/WAqhsjDd15iIAxmO31e2eeDg@DJfUgHQgoLSI/xykFlg4eYcMp8kC/LzJTe/nG@BwP8V7gRPZm@pL/FXePlk9xn@vgJOJbAWXz55/uz5swOOSHT3tdiKVTYqYqVVAYsg1na4WJkQIKwNX/uctEHIl93Xnd6qvWTvBh4IArgc/YBGnTTpfkvDROmQfIqaTbZJHAqhu8O6qmrNulqAAROIaxBUVZUK5KIVwyNHYg0qZ3oJ@dtK1/BQ8FfJbKanhQC598u1fnpTVmex8xafL2nsTGtNkc/IRvx@igAPJJDY@dlGTU2l40dlLR1/GNeysfNEY7OWVmZxiaTS6qyHG0Vww4EUh3CqkbqnpeLP0@ViP1NW0vhU4VmOE2EjttPK7CRLHkfrhMSuzXHsVnf7x7uVwLZXK6oz/zBz7GWLLxb8LDY2AWVq@uVy7BqM0i9xYQa3hMYr8dhlnMTi8/i8Hm9ysR16ZFplR6ZJLDw0jVs1/KVGLZsnyVgp6dsKpZiXCNf5vhLficVxOa3see9itFUF51C/@kqF9h2zncABxEacr4NROZfDhaSY9Grkfa4WtSeHz@yH7oHBxRobVxsOrgAGM9RwvbM/@RohI0BxnDSqsWk165/7UGo1QdlSUUlkgZRhhOkpeUG@qrFOVKMeeRV83v/C97PTrSLYVVkBu6rm0mqtpqSAo4mN3n/xe6ju63L/093HJI5LP3/7xz9UC3/7x/@a7iyNz@lykKoVYhASjUq@ELu8HF1eAj8xZ365WDN2Y0NNE/AjKXqpkBKhNFJRB0NLijE8AudVUJIxT4j5@4nzOSGRUCQ1mdKKchJ8rnx1fglVLoI1WE6lTnw@xydj@8dmTlV2trahZNtaVq1sQF0q4fF3Ev62DK8ElVN88uqKELB0at1@31SpSZJI@Z2w9Y4IW@QdrmS@EzbIq2oNNwQpeGg@WLxL4WFcXAuP19JSKk5AYiO1@rwyb6bp8h8Vhl@m7MY1PDQ28KTXslPKhp@R8ujPMKiVOnhgDWxG6rXHJ1JJSep2KaXD1VVBqMVYD2kZJFeDppKSIJepYO2O/QShkXz/C7@uqvm//eNfuWpdtT5TQdotlfKKGvvpT7cm9sQzurWfQsRblDsFEislr6iFCQ2hpEuYalfTjxUaxA4I2RMbuXoWPpB7UdIlwOuYfdvoUrmXO0f@jNZoi@kX7SZosBTqfslQqYDq80tWOC7gmBnX7/Y7GQqDpFATfb2Z5C65j9ALxn8CkkOF@2gBiuCkgGU5nZZnTdwRPSGXoPGUZobchyiQwkeou3WD6qzxRwsBqKaUuhmVZdmjWKO8HBkanoeaYGHc4z6CKP7nOqwZGemoXglDmjaMTiIGofmkHt06pN2EtC0WoUVdE7T0LECGsNyxSDYIA9xHwL9QLJjA1hBzCwJUgJx8BAiAMiR8wGaTbBEtSS7NdLqyUDM7J1DpeGJMD1S7cBgNoXVRlVAQuYLhwAmEEPxAPLYLv4aBqYw4BkAYDLbVpQpiDEanNmQUqe6lDwYFsKiewwQtGrl/f5GratXsJgktEcI/M0c4hUfrwV6dVwAWyIP3umU@Q1CBbyVwDZsdYDxNswutTmCaeyuRqIRH65zj4P/BjRZb5LWqoh4VLIBfX6xXdABlEBnRzuqwQ7aqRFELSRJmvgN579BMUQUboZDbmN4T1c8Czznk8Kex4POLQKxOo9Oifru9rtuHAHM/wW/foYZHRgx8nTxMhyMSvcNxEDuMBUUxLRq6Z7ogWNHdOIH62ISmJDHaQt0uzQc9LqNmCR5aySXxRWNhaAJvHdWg@ulsUPVtHQcq1Bs5NtWbSvW64cEhaBFAo3yVkyzbE/sCv5Xq1w2NHM2RR9VNYsvHHFM9sA4qyKJxcXdL2wXJPMBNhhh9kXSGXaKWSII2NKoa0w7BJWkkmuE2cOiI47ZlDCFLJ4ZBz6l6ZUnqA5M2aVP9oE9MaFeDAxNGHtuTHjIESxfmmSmd4kcLBKeHx1mZtqUY8nXY/dj2GF8Xp@U4Z8Qyzww2251Y0lXlERBRgMvOAGYXNyC2jPu3VC2D0ylKhoWCuwCvAjMWM5G4G4lZ8uZbUzYSLazRKzqCmVArlnGu2xH80uuK80Vzb@YF2u6ozjawiyHJNXw9V9U4arAJFbhxvt6@KlUZJ@IqyijBx/hA3x0auZFrnBMUsjkcY4BodgLNUdiLobQf0QGA9j3oWagGd@yWUd8Z5MTtJjrQ9XwCb5N7RFM5DMiUEfqKAwEGVn11GTr4QVQshzfuQsWIdOkA6Qr0zmEX/FDTjt/8MH7QutFMVRQvmjfZ8MHhoEPTqhLWLQJLLmLB3oHtmRZ9AzzzkMMVOdlI8GkAm@aTPAMdxr8enbV2jtKSMrkJKUMQgo9qgEJZBR1JDuo5jXzUlAOPB7rHvnzlK8m9uLgQqebmiWuKhocf@vQcW7ekUd8ETtiRxsZwJBkedF3X7EijAO7CJLDv@4qjwWh7ivxstXR/xt4c1/Oq/j63RLznxXFwPMfvWPaHVMsjqlf0aIM6MOk3cDsJf9sda39qM3MZtL8ytj@hGJ8jEEIQzDQzy3QyACzT7pxlehfdiu9xTjskAIdaNAJH1KfuBpahF5jMUS8M4YyRjoZebeuMrjIDJJ7NOy@SZiUMQs4Cq28fmbjF1TYuyK7r6rME9U9iaGzAiRlle8gMhn3qA0b8KsglU@5tTuuz5lL0aRgdBrVw44aLKhy5y9uBMk3v6D9l/lPwnzL/6SLRINn6tMlYMnSaY3Gw1eNe3SAkgpkFYeZMK/rCh0IGPpwoDASGnC25zeHuVGnsAN/MBvVYDRoGtIkRINxISPWXjXqjaXvGRaqZlvrQ2HmKCKhxAF1vUpxedEMzYt86t0aOt@Rko8JnGJX8fKNTZ@C3BtZWsIxhBdGGwfBloo7e/tDfYcIYAr/A/29337rfNo7s@dl8CkR22mRM3ZzESeTIHdmWE00ndo7tJJN13Gpaomx2dGtRvqiTzO/sftgX2P2@j7Cvct7hfNqnmK1/FUCCknxJ95wz@9ueiUUSQKFQKBQKQKGKIEAPo0SoBrWxG3nrSWgBTiTGOcqlNBbEjjQyx6x96ST9jdQlIb0Q1gZ0bAHC96RJhCalKDNyJKyzkQ4fRgPKY/LmORJtD74il4@XiZJTQ0VkzTp3koVVPm/QJLJDXa1ON8WkU1ccTSVZzfym@99G/953o9@hcTEfe2ZYmTDWHXuowKiXVAg9XJiqaqNq9SthUHwQdMMRzVx10U/1bE3VPCiaZYbUgybEl9G4deZand/ypH/44nSun6skrDCpVqmJk6oMSxkXhqRC8KRYrItNDCPo8iJACEZpbrFQF7uyi11VqyI41NU1xS4tJK8YySspIrmvrkHyWBej1VPDTC/onmPSTmF1nCN4ZZlGSQ0a5lQcXIQ42P8VfmxxiqHrTGUOc4HmIajY4LPW8dzajyykLaE1BQCMOAOAtJDgvDuuONMCr5xP3hIZJaQ0MkreNBuIrCAGYxG8Lr7e3YTJeA1MCn9uhecBGru5lSMnV@ataPyvJP9yvvlo/pVnP5ayOcvZjyV/6n//IR@PQVlrgFraR7n0CAIZK5l3fe0k2dY5FlXtnBY4pNWdXA6UO0fZpu/Fc120eNIdnBR7AQx0EDdevhaGE8@sH3CWo14MB@NgPHj0qCKLpojZbl79smaITvsDhJu04j2QrtcehHF/eUyd2hqc9qM49BVc8X4O9bIj1BFoHFtP1o@D2HG0rZgsYwFa@AqqbrMZ9aNxs@nCYNOrJLcP2H4T7Lm87GD9S09WeRJPGuje0B2c/Bq2xt7tMBG8RBc7jFqf3b2hToSTl5oiGdYi/Z9Sz0iDUfEgXTlyYASo0idjl4MMnQ16g1PS@s7jAnZgnSnwjRQ2EAqGQ8bFVwGWtBUrhA2PErflB54u@tN3F1U/rbqBl5RfzQLIEMNXo2kag7KjOdU1r61Oipn6Dr4f3wMb34Ob8eVV@DTOsjSvSuL3Vf3QTSFQxhSNh7ejgaaT3GrPoJNBJfkMvUoK3BnFNhvAtYFpjbLWdPZCh/jDT95ieksQf38d/W/uQFO8ftfuC2jYq4MJyZsejLHFQVNsjmRdyt7wIHtmq0tYe/uOdVFeBGffgQpBaiwLrj58utPARDi3OIlLZADfwvOwOZvhezZEq0riHJxGF776vHp9F20322E3mIRtV@f0Lbimxfu0YGN5dbeGQ9Cx0BvIWs@luctLUmkaB9ElU@Ualgn8C8@7nq0kS5RwD@@UM4aN6@mH9BnRjC2@quxW0zpgeXkR27EXEbY/EcZOwoZ0JTyslqMy/0hPwuvL7QQhOsjsWfbTar2bxOe@mzTpDjNCkreQbTK8@huI8MY224ffR6LbW0qdaxWqml52sgGz5vd4dFOPW1xheFKOm@7Gkrcx3Z15zmI1AZaKsK3vm0JmIMOOpNVybYjy5cYeG/RnZAK@8T5d/5pZpTlHoCYlWdKNI15us37hOVgZN@gXG07v6RcAT8NxUxjKtA17WjriuuKUXjC0tBb9hZR0gmJRUUiu0bByOeaZsn/5ltTZurbO1kydrUydyQjIVmllclqZKnUvoHtu6oJu2BlfI52RhLUz/dwktum//iAYYbfiy3K0XIl8tXyxXCGBvBwuV@ouCeXl9nJlmx/i5coBP3xervxED@nYWv66XDHDAhlG9MoPL/Bdi3C8t5YrW673zRkHn8PY1FtYriR9Snl@lFemCJEC7SatEUds/YFu5ngU0sTGSqWvwDGxj@UT78P4/K9E/5cQeBwcC4nY43zAmdWKKmcmDWvGkHpo2jDBV@aM5Iqezet7O2yHlWRBNSu0xrPLMHhSwxeXs8JIEEMqn2jQLyEIuVmZj5GyZrI7oqNrJw7lTs7WL2FUWR9ou5x@RJmP00o47qEub/orC0I68G54ovB1eM6gY6pjjHAm681BC0T9ZfmGRqGvs7jo3rd7iPe6s5kI27zJIr3EYC2ZTjocH85xINrBMMsknIprBJFdhjflZFCCe6eKsVTQI/OaZP6sWwbBYA9@76bmWOWAWkYEIfGodCyjLJkXWBYjKZV1lqYqg49QsGQOjfCw9ZljSm7rR84n4sbnueK6aciUlSpZcmXFJBUuwIvdeTCW2pPFax2@7b5v@WpKXmGvxQUAq2RSi8jXwXfo7wPR341CbYgwVcE8xXr@VDqrXt84y05h3k2rne1AJPpq25urHCU1pCSn1YGlmd/EazMqPkw@RMmXShPoU9q@IVuyJriFbtNrC4EFLWF0kf34eZU@fl69nlCzGkn3omCUlgJq0nCk4QmmadNuxlUaPq@LkcL720H3uzt4lO1gu/MAjxswmiK5jPLReZ@tXNKxTWJbvkCklitKBDkflybdnH4kcc9Ht8mxLX3Ya@5v7@2@/kiT7pMnTzw9R09S/DBqsdeazOMCmY26k/lgzrJl1UfgNxx2Yzs@PhuMxvc@9XMzskSENSkD8OVi2E@PcU/LMkueT41dKid5LYpqWJ/TYRBkpBJUnQBTdqTpOiaChGP3QaCBGPWW6O3zas3jEGfNZj/owegf01ezCeOlZlPPYugacyLu/X3xXvE8HnGMbInPd@k47HVFbe@pD69qh@rwVV3tvNv6SX3ce6c@1HYP4Sjj7bvN140tRf/quwd15WRM8BDLFAtKout22Ao5ePdqqfRIMeStwXAicsfd8uT7QdBTrwatEMdUz@Og9@JMXgr9cLwhpeq0HJ1gDzPi2LW9aAx7Cw62SstYKDdtvvqI6wmK8p7QmraHNW9v0I46EeV1sPYdRmFsbsupbkQ9SPLW3C/3RUlCXFU2HeJ4ybDAuqTiAeXH2Q2BCcT@CiRGDgnE2i4oTbjkv@@m4GF9/82BgneWrb3d7cZhY2/3QO3s7dPr24@N3ZdEz8bB4X5j8x2SOOObve3GTmOrxh8EgVJBwW3Kr@fx@EYUCsjOVGl9xsl3YUjdn7xld72hwavLgC@Bxmr5vA/pEwXd6PewvbzunMdQX3DxlI8KlLtU23/5nuZ8Ff6GE05zFMz2B7l3Mcf6XSqp51wbDZYNGm/rerjStJcve3we0ZsohPsK19lHisvPvjLA2YinHYUqtwUbFex9iysVHssGNFV0j2ADlDFYqSoO07e87D9nkBtUW6s7gINgqU2MCPULir4wpibrDlNM28oAKO5ZNPrYDyqvJx@I7@nDqq52PJIM6mHyQTKoR/IBqmgDtiPqsc5xPt47h3hWa/Lh195wh4@F1ZPkw2bAq9inGifpN@7SQCVhTuFYpsvBGGWXhwNGi0shFIk5PwIVdrsyMEIJkUsyUY4S2baNcuZI2HRw1KDN3iT0PFKJG2AnFHTGsXKrXkEdwjgo7EcSBvO0G/TFBCo13WHeU0/hdayq75hHSfhIvrkyHDADInRtFo@k3LbWCsO7lqOSmzM1BtpGkkM4GxO02xDYnEHgj4AhQPnMSqfFMxXfywWYQUezshsPiCOxb/s3Oz@xc/u8FWYKaKst99fo9989TWQ/s04ydoqMHXXR7@GI1Eo@yuwMRjTGWaxywD1IwdbZYDiOpA/dbAv4xImnOcqNiY1q@6W6kakNdJiusT/oW5WeEBdfU@sJMeVdamWOl7PzRHylkdiJ82kSFrs7oBOcDC5C6@zMxyHSZYjtF1KE@awcm5@TMWMi@qeTyo6/KQRwflrd2N78lP/bLz6iOItYkCDqxugQ/4gxURcNDz7nY4PFEfQuPdJM9M34/ASltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPIlrXvWiuJ2libjz7Hbd6pr/zx69fq1IqD8kkEvk8PnNT6earI1Olz2WOlTYBsWQnIUuy3jVffIaZyOsXuMqDXlgnivQhR7Bun4ptqUWIad3JeYckiw4xrrs7ge@pDbaoMIqkOJ@w@6P4s7tZXdnwiqlBibLI6RoR7RvIZc@zzFJ4vpoBt30zOJLfdwf39EbsZHr4LmjbN0L7LtzyK9fDkmnJgnV3sH@7AaxMbn8ILLXdvx6wTJKz0BJOT5jTX1pMrGlvrvGXmb7jsUdgMPdiByUBatV23ucjauNo35UCng0mVYgODrfr@/sqJ@sTKktyD0uGthaDgH1PvU2tbaM@C7tCojQli@VEeTJfMhZt5r@bBvNc4l0jKrQO4mt6JMIiuYdDC7orkXp6ZmEVgq3vWSAaymWx@2JkUHykAX@jNSAhm3aa1UBnbjMXZfKJYtsIXNPNF93YtuFnC2uZuxG4ezSxAdk2QcEpbpbM778Poh9XTD2iYMHpExrcJk2a5htaJxxQxUPKWChke/CGbjFdCiN7UbAXDe1g@FXKath/nqGYkUQJF13YEutaOdaoiX68ZNQcNkjENBDA0lMnikUzJRgRz1@e2x3qpZOem52CSMlEKOcXNldQ8eNvegpjaiTzZDVRyO2xtsTYHBksj7E7q2GvX5/pPmyh16bFw3RVJG1vrCr/j6lKZolMTYbmcxtjEgny2uPHD2@DPd0KUzz/Z2HLHDItP8e9Ia3vU5DxJObtfeLcxq5v0lMGuIF0YlpvBsxUQVJ15swpmbbzZGTjR7jIvhAhgyAViI49XaunrqZwmw9dZiQbOmeZaYM1hJOGyqiZof63m6uDQL61vnvfX58MNmSC6eA3WOW/GYziML2VZzmgsT7hSn72Wzga9Tmb3GfqAYrL15huvGzHt@3E4FVahUQ@b7Nb0tG3k8Ts1jd7DVwJby8WLs@CMXb31qe39/LldbupO43XdfWAXbF2MnuRuVHOs2TPvah/EwIsg3lfAtMH3@G7H1foH@HgG5BEJr7N5zJtvFtxY4qQ1nzEsce0WaiWreXp3u/EraAPlyV@7n6scv4PVJB3Yet7O968nfXSeqY8IRcP@y6V8nP5Qo6L0jds6AJSFoT0Jr5bExZuahhLSVyvOR3APgoHW@GV7J6x5WRQLD8trT1zuHV9f@z3jp4d@w9a1ZyiyTfo9@Lz0WX78@ng7KKjumr468lVa/L7b0o9fgQP72r1B/HgXV6rFtlb8RMF5@/PSsy5GsEf2Rs5ArQXJHK1UssqXYev31MeP/CiuYIbElNcqh70DBfiit242jtaO672q6X13lH/eB2X/MYr1fFKecXFhx9oFiUZIyfzR@NjzKn2rmvYv1DwMMtxkfXVEMVXQ@jLm2AUDV7Xdl9mduOgAGALTNt684Y6myc7C7Bmw92TQj@8dPU2ma/AsQ4UJGeBbwWVcd2d95OxHdOOCDPqFZ@02fiK/048Z6FUOB@OB5xi3FGCtdTX6KuzYK4xlXhHgbIcRcZpJe4XEJw0j4uDIfk6ESvqfFnUtTLuTnoWiCOUZHGY@5TL4U4hENV3uY6OnbgQBq0zINEltforF8PdZLwRq8UF3sWDKUcw4gsTpWM84gCEfoZ82oAqWHOP@dqHQ83HexkP8oX3qMZ8T4YN5B3WFJEC82/1he83cfnnRAAh/ILoXAW9xak1L1Ik5e4gby7AeVt24Y9jBlyrlE5ZQGMBW@qrpsDZUpxphGo1mej7wiXIKbSi/3QL8mV@m2lGkt@T7EwSPqfWbzFoyV3KSRv46abFXKtY3hQzmS1SLNxKDex00fLoTUjDaqK2wm6XkBZaLKTkwCPf79X1ryT1x0eo8zhBXtLzM@n5THpB0gWpNFeBJvg0U8XOlFv8kub7pnJpNn@mrqpi5aVAPd0qkEqS5l2/KW9cGA@aUZp5I@lK4cok4XkmIW@l/Dyn9yXlXqZMwuBJ@pGka/5e1T2fYJnJ@yJbP34d3UEhG89qW5MpLi30o@6PMmklKWCzHFFTKSnOQVuVGVRVfQdTixPS4LDPz8N2o5pCWSkbicNjJrfx/EWuoJWMH91pNOQW48zAmjNGLCpxnStMuCu@sEj1cPI9CwTDBKMpM3I3TOGJLjyxwCLXPVOt3IKcGeDUtOkhXsW9yK/4YwZ7FjmTb3F@4oJgfiWNl9vNWQKx0L2Xm0@mrDTBdRH5qBt1wyyS1j2ZhjhfSOxau8BJnaHcwe5gG/xeIidsQWEkxQzdkxRN6TRD2bDvdV2IxG/O34sPnJcB6djDbnilalhmBHwLy8lccB@H8TiGPyp2jROfD4ddnDqywnfJV6h1@IjVxzhuSSFaM3vBacCyR/L7eNIX0qlQQe0B8iUMRNKE@Pz0FJfJcAN2cAnRih2XaFxwav2JbGjQmHm4KtfMQwXnGyyAu9GpjYT0nIweUDoeBq2w4JCOFpP240hTO5GOdcz76bg3Aq9nNKVVHOdfzqPW562XOM99Ui49LFsku9DHwaXCw0fpBSsikklYhXvDx@VHjmOdDbfkbDgPgL56jYn@PfFmeBH2@6FToxmDM8aktMbh6CJsFxxnP0wOgQEXrIyTSdzDHpyPWrK5Q0pXQMyIW8KxL8dhxGH4xfwsx8UtPivzHRxapafN1NUXURsENDdOOgOcDvOBBdwECD1QqBeOiSgPPJVFic@eNS6su/SwEUXUgJ8T62wiIUN/MI5a1DO8k@V0CZQcg6SV9dtTmFB9rW6Ay8GFeQjgekxKAYOAOUq6CQdHH5p/Fw5KN8ycsQemZ4ok/QY8Vmi4h6OIpG9KYO4VLmbhTh18@KpxoA72dg4/1Pbrip7f7u@9b2zXt9XmRz7jxkE5exZWr/Zek3RJTtPl1HyPPuRqB1QyxwlObfejqv/17X794EDt7avGm7evGwSNwO/Xdg8b9QNfNXa3Xr/b5tN3gqB29w7V68abxiFlO9zzuVZTzEnLqb0d9aa@v/WKXmubjdeNw49c407jcBeV4VS/pt7W9g8bW@9e1/bV23f7b/cO6goNc7YbB1uva4039e0C1U91qvr7@u6hOnhVe/16qqF7H3br@4qNBKxWbtYJy9omLWFRE7dzu7Ff3zpEg9KnLSIeIfjaVwdv61sNPNT/Wqfm1PY/@hroQf1f3lEmSlTbtTe1l9Q4x72FKtQvW@/263CbBEocvNs8OGwcvjusq5d7e9tM64P6/vvGVv1gXTmv9w6YYO8O6j7VcVjjqgkGUYvS6Xnz3UGD6dbYPaQ5491b2Dt41MkfiDCEZY2KbjOBYQaB1hKR9vY/AirowB3gqw@v6vR9HzRlatVABVhUbB3a2ahCIuKh3Uy1W3/5uvGyvrtVR/IewHxoHNQ96rDGATI0YJDxkViHKn3HrUY/EV7ySMzqGM71uTtVY0fVtt83gLnOTRxw0NDcwmTbeqVpXoAjYWsTJRpgzyDo2RsrndlPFyGcYs7uyMzfo0k8Jm3tbddpRtZOrnJpwjuadZ5OuVKy02imSRLpNeOyph2enJ82o35ngDumSTHZ@OjFpz7CdXkIMvTJuSFant5f4QKLi83m@1qTFroHzabn36VkBo3bSuht8JtyebqNCEKBlTc2fioVofvzDKE2ftAHnWyohwMI5BTq/yCmb0Ev9FSx2A51MVzeB2CzdRTLsckZjlJINPJlR0RHSqvknQl@jzQ7cEHXgC@0mtgnhWUkZxrE9Kf/NX2RycH6QNJZtruKRSxiGY3o99BUI5WwSwT@oz0SRB2ushCH4edTt2RXhzV/4XQwaMMzrC7Dece0Djx1vVuKn4SnU8Xz0@UZWT521qEWYrPuZhUmOX/WJFO6XwojbpmLP80x/3gGG/H5gF1Troo3q/WmpfuDFIdFkq@0awtcr@BOhs73pvbXxges5kqrj9anvr9KvsvYgr0g/OrShHfE5Y7559WxZKABxr44iCSR9pBRLFpljL1JkvmSMp4h02XUhuUPzdVnIc/rRBJSZM@Drl0nZuNRdGVjT3L45X7tzea7nR0SncD20dPHT9bWncTt1l99@f2IetjDLXsdG9I8TnoaJ1mjZIsUHx4plhvylP2ZgYtFZIRHetNp/BF@HhK7jawlEwQZmhsjVFgfJnq5EHTIKXbAcc8x/Dp3ZGoGcDNN9dCaXnDFKn5AuhLzgDZm6U64167wB7CT4W@GeNIgzUCaxdjnL3EurS5Y7uV2jKkoL27YcQ@yFHKGj8WNW0ID3upi@1ncruU3zdtWL8Ziyojxyt3OJQmJe9NYKGNX0ZeR/Zb9jOgNYPYeRl/@qvmNHj9qB3fs7i6Ix7XxAZFxJymJfep0M1o3@khDPkaEEDhVMzU9V9jl9zRSPPb0dnLiGMQaDYwKouPAxjcLeD3xIzJdJVvAvlj21BfhVDjvAJx1zbH6nTh3XnM0lHXjP0S/G68USmAlTk6EapdJHY7J8jHxY2HImSHTn6IHw/8n0mQO/Oe04iToKbUsJ4B3oiRDFVrR8pWJEl2agwbrdCOlpv3pYwrmm90xZ0nD9OnNldyvIRLo3pmYDx/Z7WHHnUMAMDk2Nuzxm5iknQW0dHqR83RxnJP0W72hq/RcYaaKGbj5tWOf1S7fnK3gxVOe7DVZFb6mouqFLNxOeNTTkmlqKa/uxzkB5xn/H8UHvAGSDHjm0jOxWp3mrJIeZUYOaFdL1oTTTjwmkVr67dpTuwfKcpGZkf365MsQikBvAJ/ZdnKolIES89ysx0WeidUhe8GDH3MskzH5aJd1J2yI2Q0B536bN0MQTWV8iQmiK9DZVV8KTbn32VAElaRWh6mfQYhbr0Ck5Wn1MsGedybBoQn27/riWz@UXS2ToyAOPjSG9nX5gnoTTAjl7t2aLSxWfHAw8GG7iMpkW0KXR@SY1mAwItUxQLsJRz@aeAX1QW86hP34fKT9F9J8Fo30joRR@qkaqE2yeudpRnzXM2pxNMZthXaB@YOb1AthISruSa7ya8ol5jU8umE2HaOrlbJyn6cpz4km7JaUifhcrSF6LucSgmqXoSFTMIqTxQXbbHI9OHdIht/lYPQZcz9UoH47bCeeSS2QvBcondTos4/H1liaPhzEvKNBXYEdkIQSZdlISwxVaY5@otlJ2zXlUu@Y8F3KLfn@ehImNdZSVFHKuLp2Yr61PHUmqLSqXYMmzkLLq48ZlXkLrm/XLsbYW2j22FrlPvUTkVIRJaJ636iOeBK5mTx9xJPe5K/ejzF66AvOuLUKCoShs@JcdVbOMX6wKfgQhaO2vSdKmkw7GGL7jZc@gz7zotk61G7/WsE4Die0AmgVo6siw2i6fxmc9Ztbg25wGg2igNZp8Dx/JRIPjxN@RIedjgaXMQdFkuicVqb2JH0W/zLihg3vybnkuuWaKx6HQ9c2UxiPJrUzcRPBO@cwAkzj9zJ/D6d9pCVlHj1OCznZ@6dsj1f21q8t@7A8r7Cc6AOAFnAbUxYUcod0zBeTrMun6zMZTm7KYOF4ovIq8K6x2Mtg/IxIxMcwGYwNMjNmCXYjsDK7FuOj9pXfZh@EIzhaCrdDxOuJXf7sB4jMTlLkR1gKVFT5ackqKqcoV/BDiIfJ9eReffJPxp4Q@BPolx/O45Z5jMAirmO8LcWyXtFeRgkXNg@MWEazJCYpFp1Gfev6Ice9uJqGmk2eXEcNtvwhpUi72ZvhSoxIlxY@iN3nNknkNCceJpVlteyx3w6oILWxW7qeYcPb7Gd58OMQV3bOIJi2NGTXQvo6UrWISgglPWVea6MsPpVvHzGrq3fttSkCVueZnFnR0t2c0Vz4Bkok8yuOtQYjEsa5KeppU4/leDwYLt@RetfKjrme2ebRuuV5txoCC7NVabJ80GbSVid4nKw70/hMMU2WYmxpRjyE5Ss/J2w@TcSrahPjrdqc3EKH62iW2k0lk0rS320Z@5gUL2DRayaaZEgx7nBSup58P2pSw5vXSxANU5ZXTZYYTYiM5kQeLVBTZEqodHcKMfdp3Kfo0SbKod420c7un2uJOm0kZ1yemqSMk0vQE47bcWmT5NKwA@MLuIkTDTcRUonCeeVP@CivnD@Bk2EkCEBoxWE@3YeSHdy0s6b4iKMDdNwmrIXKkET0tGFbOCRO/xOCsVd@vbmjLR6ak3z5eF0gXSWQaFXBuW6CZO6b0@tR84qhzJCChvgcUiQtmpFNZ3dv1Z9tC@UjCFKak7Wlb8lHYzy1QtjQHzupeQUdOK1Kl8yMqOxAaLJooLFAq5TTbijLVWh/0Ug4HtYNehjRAkI@u/hZ0SXgznutlFAbRa7aE2TxNLlltHkqvyFFUoaSd5BfD0VRdXnhSgBCwZjKV8sEAW5NGXscCrDrHZvzMojqPqKC1TKGJX1kr6ipneecdBBVZ3j02MpRmpfjmQ0jPxcIKRbz86SIkM4yP0sKhSa6ubhYOZ7Mb0@agxRiw/tCceoK3StZGiY9JwTkaNslL5UoR2XllzQHc@Kjx14mMeFvTn1WslJL06lEnwTDo3x5OvVpKZOaqXZ1NVs0U5Lo4dm1ZhKJFJ6NcCIV/tx/fDXFdnme2IRai4yMlqHtsxENnVaZtG4r/Bqr53wp2@gYBp59M9wsv5oSYiXjlP1mB@xqmY8M4Lv9T7fWWKYaTHSsAPZLZy67uLIgZI01h6kezcJK13jaSxwUmDXtoKPeH@7sZNy@nkyMoVEvHD0ulUpg4hPb@b2xrcZWUjQoZnMXO@fdbnF4@ZfR@5Miy/4w5JAAFbOCDqlLaFDEhcHoVCJDAAfKitx5fZEVa/3zTscOwYATSnQedZvk1N4QFE9AUWL08v6QN4AYpJ5gf0ED0b5fVDL6LgNRNDUUcwxFpWESfJEzp2dEHnzowD47OaliYBDMxpqJ5i2vuvEFMwgim3Bnsfti70tqnpx7FXa7A199QFhleApY@DZdYGfHLlCSLDhh5Nu95zH7o/VVeBF1rXvFyGLzOsCZicnEmTB@4eEbfz88rV8N3dzRzzmaVqjJK2jmCvxT@yp3mvO0s/g7gBU@JLTvlLsXDN0W02k6M031egSnT4TRw7I/d@2TyeLxnpim2e25QdT56BbYWQM13WNdwPiy5@7lllyTPSFu7tNVuQMalgSGxgk@V@5WAlfN/nli8WLc6dxNKnIYAOnY75KIEgnlzwlEPgPgEaiHH9ETXrR/ytOw3plyKCIKDoJ1zModFGiigOPcb1V/u3RrtZpaGq6sqFptkx7yeVXbrKltfNjcVNv0von3H6qrjx@vi8zd9r7Qx03z8ZvaJBi8w7nSOhtt0yulVXFvDNba6OKlYnXJX19qVp9vrMfFo9omrvXT07//1//@7//tfxRr@uV/4WWTX45@TjIVCoXiUuvL0g/f1vF@tH28vHRytDQ8Xj5dB5f9nb2GDxrjfJCajxZGJ86izALWV7YjNets9j6jiyoTy68XjD6TdKmoxVZcXNRfY4kcxTJ2sRVa30PcozyhJbwJOjC9lHcQ1K0XTLAdT73TCmGAR/MNUZJwgR2olJezFbNxD3cwSYbkVGVRe@JhnfUixJ2W1JMC7uLSjJWP@nHYxw74Beu80jzHCeg3Gjc1/xZ/fhOfbg6u1INPrnpQUg989SCX45/y2jP66i0VI9zOlWy0HMjlfEpJjxZgZqjiiBU9Xj9wrJ0pcjvOEofsASTjpoIzyy04P1n98WUZCbgWnzoLiPapZIuED5lQZPHLUv8bdcsXyvEtl7lqw4pCU69iuDLrRCXpX6hAQSyGAGnNPSFIZUBV4qSPbyTjqWi@6L52OJoQAwZZ91/u8LjHB5qLlvra5jmzlkKYIzafl6@YG9flMjSjjRSpP0WAD1RkOVnim4TLi8uOWHlbreRmyi1su32a@cTWYRKOjW26FPqbsphArLltwi319b0WbcgtxysqFyXHK1ZVuWnbb@VYRXrn3XE01NcVuHYMqC9Jbd9kJKFHGZDAEZ/9ldkRxhsFxlPUVLdIsKyJag/QdBkJfX01nTrYK8jJkUWE4s8uje2vU2PbK/ItEcMOwgOMVGLK1wmibqy9royY2KfB6ATRAYMOB1Qby7kZ7@chausUxoNOgnSBIbPJeTqeqSmLw1Fw2gt8tbg7OBwFkwZNW6T5jFsFj1oIF0xAAoNPVz2veQZhaZHuEqZI0hS2HELwgu5Eh0eTvs0ld07QpWYoaLcrGAQZdmJKhl8zfTVFx5Srv6MTbJRnhHdyGqlFLEteWBppSDn72gwPs5mh45ga7LGTDJycI6gmI9Pwgi50jom2xwe/JMm78BGg687pW4D6KsLaM9SP2ek07AeZyWnYdcxF/@K6knkR45lDUYo1kqOhPCmnEe@AFemRP2e9QMjcZNwZOQuuu/Ap1uHcFu15hJ18J7b4xUBFSQA6DmDGN0PUu34kwnJqhkpjYBRUgy3/CUKnG5wSfpPLYAJW/LTo/niv6B39/Kl//MD91P/66XePMdEi2cyyebWoD7ONxNJjhWbGop95NVZpsXE1@KmfzfCpr@QOi0UCQqToHv1cPP5aJIQ@LXreg@KnRSFIpsuASfHm@ooAX5xBczGLRXHRWfAeeKbz3R/LnqK5lX/Rh/LBk1/CwiwqeZue1jmjDoHie7q/ncuVk7j4dLX0aLX8iFZCp@FVfhSeY77Nx@cn4RWpEjGWszT1fPo9ww0ZQny7ioN1@nhF7ZSwJnL3JNaXlLQI1cOc63EStqIyBeEJyk9UZnepuOLiJXkCHD5iwe8rYjmTl31BiemgxX0u5s940EM9QQy5Nn07RDgSVgZiI8JbqHlANsFXruNQzwyXZb7nVFBb8N3KQKh7i4vWbNEf9PNaWfMKy@tQonFrpvu09LQ0PUZnhmhmhC5pZWr5nipv/Pjk3/7n3m@L48WN1eKHEf2OF39bXHu6KI/0QG8PzdvF4sbic2Rb@7Y4KdIamB6f/Nv/pvIbfyE4SJk8pz8bjw2stcniRr7KRb4ubqzRQ3l1ler9P//6r9SGJVmxIRbrUtNXjNi6ochW0GfepXTVQCtlWbqcihW@mAUYYmFIa3N6gWHU1erTEm/TLWqriotQe74y9ih6imfDrDGbCslOhrGnIM1IClRRQV5AGhOKjrJsN4zZBpg3RVP9cr@wFtMK4BdtzpFUmZhu3I9hMrQkyyLqQFdqpPW8PGyUfswl5h2VnLEpWTcqJJZ2WtY@fbhO7PB2EI6jVtZKwgzXXiu4DE8K4MNC2D6nNVU/7g5@HRUviCV75dWnxQ4294tsx10cMqT8cFL4nRRBHQyIFoZsdOqrEfXAoAcXXj5HCyKFfic5kzLxJEnLHoYt2cPKxiSmLHLHz5fjYTSnkKrSLv8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qc@ldzbr6jcSpJR8vGa1wM2b9k4VrvAyIs17JBlU8HhNmB30LSnUBud8iUkLgWv65KlELTbzUCnuc5CzoRK852Fs7A7rOY64t4dvlNxYqLpL2rmtVDyEXYQ8nkWdIDVC8cBLdGrOf6C9XhaA9yk6LPWxFVcStaOzqtX9e0qR125oepLqfqSehRaQlpPwjOWNzZlZxPZUsVW5Shs4khtbsVUW2yCNo8K/AMMYumWRgfXEnRz@AYkUS1tjrYqs7vN57Uw8chlKHf2ZGtRIlc7i@nlR9/kkBvU0J1Qb0EqIwEBL7gVWCjT@4HcgKiaMKNR3xF/flPJxr@HBsNt2IMrUdttnTgflWmpf4HYN9GY71IqIoH2K2vbYDsyeySgExdbSQjaHDZech5YqlPhxRZnNN1R4TDQxiVULif7VEctlYSX7ejotRIogj7kSuXVh48erz15@gxRzhZ0a@eDQaECVgHDs4BgsEbt0iIb36vV3HJOPiEE9WyVgD4PLA7gYNZ16XnG7fOld69aLmlgpRzDuuQwGlJcb1cyyBTiKCxgRqA1ijvKue6PlSM07PhT2/tK/4i/jX9AZjjjjjYQ0lv98Db1TOX0xOFAlQUzO8VxH8KDiqdT7LzhoLMPbxMhbF2F7ami1/AAMT4bDc5Pz2zuKGjXVoc0YIjg7JcaK6iX4Th1MGZhBV1Ubzg0rNsXVQPvaLYFMMrFlACdT4DTMNN@KwNtaYrRsUyTEDxr4sYqjhAt01GbnZk7@wNV392eRmzRDkPHcAu2ZSspd@zJDA5kEKvXau4hUVd7u@CrpFom@RmvyizgSshX5uvwAe5KtxCI2qKKkdWsN4zdm8hSZl5MXZumRakfgdccmOXS7aQ091pNK0AQIwj1blIixPzkPMcmWYqT3ckYp@DlXMWyEX0TxTE7mNOV5TxtUcqZOKrAgnMNQOzblHLSkFIFPcqPdQ68LL2NYI5yKxpbA9oMOVmphnNzcpgJtrqNxQE2oo4bWqD9jd0tX23X6c/Oh20fivJm7Se0OwnxfD2@ZY1vuaIaO6YLbG@xbHMLm6nfcEWJmKWkHcamCEL4diQqYph6Dag3djTtZVAfZcb2ccoVYNdAK@Fmd1QPEjh64T2QBb14T1xx8HUd/laRzatZSZO4VNHDQra4bh7YFk0W0loTSELKO4BYnQaROGpJuX0hZXixQGfNO9BrF8PYjZ35PJ1hWVlQkdq@UySyZ3n2WsrcxBarmi1WK@jHm/iC@fZG3jgJOwN9Fy1hjlt4494f44383Zkj//8Fc9T/OdzxUHPHwwpkj3BH4jacb3RyGPbBHI45mfAc3GxHpxH2hzrWKxpR8i0ALPCAIe6QUmK5hLZdI06UOz9hZXo@gpHQ6mNcDPhDjX@kG/@oApnLj9vh/6uNz/@DG/9YN/5xBXPNnJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JUJXSzH@Z2L9Rdyeb90Zau6ZauVTCbzunm//SW5v@DWvpEt/RJBR4T5MBB3NffzM2iidQOthqN1Nyi4GinXS7i2M/nSg9rr3Y1R4uHTvc8PqtCW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OItIbEOTtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStdj@gJSoQ0b2yN9EKFFHJfEtPTpkKqP6bSN5l87oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZS8d4qL56iCZq2vJvLLNPpDV1uH@65X/ImToBZ/1LTRCHl17GXa7Ziaxl2CHidcp3RirOYB9oNccGVbR5GRkx/q2d8IuC9dLNXZsMTUvzl8kyFEbzv9oLdWDvmFF5caWEdGmoMubVRVMc83yQr5Q2yXT/CbrFv8hLn2mufRZRe3rhcF1pAr0hp/mxXSdtvr48U1zgJQq4AcDsORT/htG1f8F)

rSNBATWPL doesn't like `::` preceded by alphanumeric character, so Haskell and Thue/Twue code was adjusted for that.

rSNBATWPL cares about `(){}` being balanced, this is especially important before print statement.
Cases when braces are not braces: `\(` `'(`, so I added spaces in `' )` in Ruby/Python code.

rSNBATWPL code:

```
#}}};print{408}{{s{{\}
```

C code accidentally closes `)` because of `\(`, rSNBATWPL code is placed after that to avoid dealing with `()`.
`#` is for Flaks, `\}` is for Bracmat.

Answer (score 3):

## 425. Python 3.1.0, 18615 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PYdSD4saPh@RE3waziE0@@ySQzs7KyurJVj1RmVndbJIsFgiCJThBgAWAmWZms6NY4tGpL9tiy2pZlyS3L41l57YnxTsys5Rh5J8KeiP0y4ZhP/gEl27EbtkP6B9pz7gVAMpPMqpbHG44FCeA@z7333HPPPee@0NG8wc9@FsOLHDrWtG85PvENzydd1zwzXJHcmZIdzfTyapbjMNSu2x8PDdv3KlyMKIRYmt0fa32D9EzLN9wM8QyDdAzLOQd/lZCtsT32jG4dbFlCbOOcHNi62QUIxHdODdt8YbjglyPkrmFdDi99ojvDoWZ3PTJyTdunvnlCDjWw9Mb6KdE6nu9qum86NngVlpIoLtlKhDx0XM8ASI5ueJ6DsMpLQRSZvKNBeiPLmFyBrCjkfdNwu4TmYuQaLC@KSt47uXfvqmuWfEFwbHIPc3jFK0d2x75z4F@Fnye7fcPWiCqWRfWqZwHw5BtWSS7JV72KUFWGb@pX0ymR3V7PtA3yEMp61bNMdM8TPN01Rz4HVUnumS5UsxZUJ9E1G6oNKzVFjOHInxKBEYJmWVEle0TzyNgbaxYNZ4@HHcMNA3q@5vqm3Sfnpj8g/sD0ong0tDfSdEPoGpY5NH2jSywTIjm9AAqAtrvk1JieOy7UfQDTsa0pRDR0s2dilDAfABCvhD8wGJyhNgXCsX2gEqIRD7JhGSG0JBeD8HeNzrhPnLE/GvsE8tY1Pa1jAdDOlHSNnja2/AzpgB9UCXU/Hxh2QNUATgQQJw7L1YdjmjVjTvxat0tkIGjIx6lBTMAazVaFZLPgThwXsAahwhwFwCiBszIaE6hhqLOeUyF5WQb//cgFc6tZnhNkZjlr6GlDo6V1hnAPXafvakPARtegOH3v4JB4uuOCDW4MyxrWTWB0zSdbWyS@/@hunNSjahHdDhdVUY1cQBXEQk9yplljoJDFmnCgftwoNodVFt@IV0gc0KLKJJcjOWi/JaLmAUmKXAYDMAI1q8BdIGqJ5BRob3mShcBZFRp3AXygQZCcnI9nMPGeq/VNy2Cg@wi6iG0H4qjwlHMkC80iW8iy0H3H6rGgOs1FkWRLpFAkxTwpwrNMyipkA9PMQYvJw12AGyCWIY8ASM1CjmWVAZs3CiBiJMQ90tOGpjUNUqBJ6CSvkCJAhcIoAF0tARR4Z7N4Z@EuIbTlaxG2P4CqGGhnAF6wzFPkZUbEzrB@JXhJqZRE@SYyZpa8N8DkAa@A0XyJFCH5AmAkB1kAtKslSD4vs4J4A8OygmgDD6PR3BZluCHnRcBFCapGBpzKiNQi3GAH1qkCj1SBIarA41TgS6oK5iwmAeGwrgpQz4UcS2ageaeQEEtH7dIKAL4PYBTEOPJDBZEEEKDWCKAaaCAHVJJFKslnCeQf8lIsEKCAkkJKOVIqEsBnWSZQPwrkC0lIAVasQH4UBAZ0oAAhKJAnBbCtAFAlmyfcArKVLPpD3CzEBdQoOYiTAzNUnFLAG@IBdSiQpAJpqmp5TqGQNzUP5c1nKemqBajdIvgB3lTIqwokhfSqlsAf45YAhyWk7GI8wxChIR6gVrAtAC0CMvKQHwoXwoJZLQbEq1mjgdZBxs9idnoYtYBtpIBohKgyFg/eOcQmZEUGMNgaIPsqUECWNiV456LkLQWANBC80TUp97awB1EiDBUzlCA/1Eb@HG1KgeZoNPUHkZvK3BzgqiZwRqOv6dPIE1phJvKcuxay6KpSRjwHJOfQ1QO264w9aw4kMuRUmpRxZlpztxJ16xpat2d6g5fzvOZoIh1D823zdJ5KPp9ZQKq24FFAjyWnYnYxrG8K0Jf1B2ial0UtYpiRE1XQUpYVhWavY/TGdt8QyqWF/FEff@z60OvM0ywzZ9fs96EHn8NRMrSYtBedO@dpDq1sFjr30BGxi2m6JvTtt4k@ANkk8iwz@OXyHEZWRRhTrYNdvgCyGnQRZezUeuaEdG7rtEuZZzBL8aQPzFEYuLI28ELl0kQmpcICbVDMvSjJEXvGqyV@6Jh2Ik7iSW7GQUfE5M/Fbhx6u/exC8NOGUkXOl2HihRz9pmww24zCUhblgCgS7ZQUuoYuobdM3ZWBu1sQzimLxJIBIRIwzlD4Zb2mEvJeLRX7bgoy4II1DVcl2BYEIC9DO1/vXHHM56PUcia56sHHboB/X5PM60oA7Qf0XwqHcA77kF60@Vs91xnSDubIfavluOM1sgy0JufI6D7zrkxz/q8s9dGIwtEKnA3mEQHmTnXqFRORfjFVFmGIBLGgwoHgDQpEEVM19Ap7oOiQ@wsCC3LWawQtX47i1DuLMhaWWgsIId4GMceW1YFhCBDJ9m61DXOJHRh8tiyHIZ5CCU0kLMCEB0NxG7MOc1FBOm2KlLZ7ySsWc8ZLheN9a8HUdEHJkpN1rk2hdrrQddqTLQhKAcEJXBouWQIFMNqEGsCtAgs1gHpOnbcj6CcuyDhQqGjklApGnHim0MDdCQHomCN52imsXenOetMgZQptnIiVYpYTq4gSuSuIoo55BYcWGMBWbA71hFrmLZpUwoCcclDBcAFVsncON8lzaYGtwvC3ijQA0U0YMBjzNqCOuGx1h6I5TqFiAKsYXugoXgiMVFLA8rvOz0gtnMTyg4MC6LOYesUCYiCyGki6iJHUY4ENDy1iEn00YiAO3RKQJ735BLIp86HJnkBntYA9At97LpTMhlBTZhDCOXrTq8H1PvCGA0ABBl2iT7VoXlCJVPq8Qa2NuK6DmUz@mi5sHPbpgFhbNRb9g5/kfQNQD7ItD3UGpHw58UYjWhBKEI0m8m7tgb4woLooylFDhebx@g5jojuXcfwKMk47mnEADAxz@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@auIiUvTeuGNOrirqOjqKH3rcmeaSHuroLoge0IgS8Z4XT1apO4254MVLzsiXaFT25CEgDSRClSd6oPZDV3EPGM3x1NYT/FIT4zOEH/u9Ep8EA0Zkkhp5FxSGq7lDJQKJZngK7ZraqqQPnbggwFNAN5oT9JBE9NBckDagEYKuWS53Oxq5BO7hEmGyxxSSUDFRxFyUlmF3o7QCRGBeFssrsiQ8V6cGYaFvwxJgcFpy2kksIfANMUEj8uAgSUEPiw5U5mN@VLphjmObDuyRBBNIkuQiEoGhA0jQzJgggpi66bcDoeX27VB82ajVgNhApgK22U0u6rXhoKcInBoCi1QmCRIRfefYx7aRSEJ5MfCM5QaEJ6DUWp1c@AMXWhy1zzgIBGjlbKTkELFBPT8yT8fdqxVtoyMG4rHVgehk6j5f5UAEYK2hdhNW40tYBd03jlhF4sX4FPQ14qWuWKF8EMw1PBSCa0FWFmo4gTkIaHUliljUwG1O0HtT3QpEAmaCxs64UQeyfxqMdUWMKBPIBGGjvdZSGRBsDgwOOdw9uV8L2iLzlDqmXVlysBxds6jzJgbnw7gPDu4c7R79YnsFDMvsVK46SGauVMCudjwR@vZYyolqZXMRxhzw3fbNsDHichieC7yJ4EwWRKWpDp3LJETn46MvXEUJSEKIDpoCmPG@ItKwMCB0cR3NG1zphEk/nYYkoyhhWCIckBBmZMCso78W5udw/OIFVt7VTI0Cd8yZNdYYgNBROrDDeCJ6XhHAQq9Oj/WINC7IoqaNExlz02LIMD/voOx8NTNUoF4gmXce39s/qlGwweiaQINIng@ylOZ2RaB5awyK@KowwP7ApJO0OM84StU0rysRrOtLCJ7XLVkDHwCgxiM6RLCGYdG8AeR972rZqKugRxRA7RTCVblyUR7SP29GF/KBXZyOiu@qXpR6zDuryGlljxX5Lndbej5vFHPlxW5Ln6fZXQRK5w2gHwjlRhe8Tj0BXcS5FBmI1UH2jx9cy7hHhUhQBYQwZ55FRJqWZ3GovQgmiXvSHuhpjmWI71OOxxM@KUnxcOpA1D2qgi6E35@YfkJOsreShLCQ@u7ugXo3DBwMXNPxDKo0oEaOPZPbw7lA3QMasR3L6TskBXGYdBgmCGLT2mLu9h37Wg1p6IhFjeF0IvBfHL7RRtDXmC@o@khjLSqtbGJSs71z4NJKIYtIohiioCQaXvxQO9MAXfNyHx98aR86ESUvy5FZphegYCEORRea9AVX6kAESEgM8rOygNH847XWHnoICxOAWOiA0UURd@feKx0pxxSlleFXZuld5xrGP3SmV0gLXBhpgWEBZQePDh8cPNp/uPtB01fz@SV7Ti4XAHGQXgdkIXHA8IatNcWaJhYLwcWgbbjYvIALjEFBCSeUxp4LjFvEICLLwBqqYTO3iXedgR33klcLc46@woe2zkjoITY@FjSICIp210JlxGUz29ifI/0MfH/kVSQJWvlg3BFBaZU@1B1L60s0HnQMliUpqLocPMbRDW9VDMiMNzVYDDbEBaLDlI4jatbQAeWFzo8jayAJBp6OXVlmfwC6ME6iG25SjCiYlkbqgoYAurIUlY0yYGoD3AbvsJ54RtpvK2qJ0bUiqzmJD4MtNX8Iu9EzQHVKQG8FqEhesZLm7eZtMgUujZCuAokRMUUHOTyCfYFFQJCkY6eo54fIodwCR02RV1AcPR/jmC5wKSkv54pKIS@BWgZqGsisAo68CUPN1weC7wgAT3B6dNxggQp7nq7ZPTEVGMLMgtx3C4qabTxtNu0WCOjN2zRvODXdmLYaSitZJdejpILwySpQ71LxkHZDB6BdagTSpG@yhp91tevsrKvR1tUlkj8cBX2OMCIPd0GQeuEAv@4ai20PI0iLnlJqKayEgV9KKwaELIzK4QMxJUGDgp4WSE/CfAkg9KJ4CJQDfGshApmPZkQC09QfAP/IksQeNSWvS7jonA24xnJWcGhYHE2B5dFAyLSFLGYo9KAJjhgEzEocVCCUeNA/zrJABxJOXGDpI6gmNqC1Bx0BqHMeDkX62AXjnM2YjQ1jkwysOOC5K3yJaMKLm4SLMDQAfvVHP@wFcCKxTSR3NKQ4wMIVyS6IKJInyAKgL58Sn440dA1U43F9xBPbREVE5KivAF1XfLMt@u4G4SGtV3/0p68@/s6rr3/86uNPX338668@@@NXn/37DeEl6pj1rXSzKYiZRovw8WuZv7Wv3tq9c@tOieYQ5EnI/P/9S7/@d7/xK8t5X5Hujz/62o8/@uW//ZWP/@aHH/34oy//5Edf/8mPvvqTH33yRuna/9evOvp/@9gJkjzHoZHFBIP0ILnBAHrR@yC1NVK3zi/IxsYGRN/Y2Iaa2NjeJmmyDU8BnhvQb26Dbwae26QBvhukRWYtDjRYj6wY7RPp@LloaPqgDdxSNxLZpAhd3sXl5JIMBo2JCO38lNdTfGtGZ5doX4AzLizTe1hpx3SJDOb9Xei@mW2e@XVJN6RmQ262mheJZjedbM6kjNICLbtt4sNLqMmGIooCuCFvSUjiRWkmRXmb0JAQSNQH7jxndMKOrdhBXZoR/D1zAj0RsEogpMUxecpa6OQODq1@yRgNpu5igGi8CuRTHHueLwTB9TLI/xb5ywsWf1EUWtKRQ4mRhQOxEIe9UNIYTRlf5FhOm9LSOqSwxzoTekPH16T3RFA3xIWOJr4RlwQB@hDqwyDRYj80PR1UC802nLG3OEa3cugQUwfXk8EY2PfewBxxhj5wgNJ3ACaJZkkQyTjhI7BpozBaVxfhxmaNLAOnGKA3pmt0TKh82nrpKIZCkz7TLLMbjWXnC6PnYpRalcYhMiZk9m3HNQRABMTg6IIkut6Nq4ezuQd0pOgarwx8aReAfNc0/Ay5ZzkaxahjAy0sUCPOhczjgz4LUY6MLmfZROiBaCGyGnCNrpTi6Nym4w6AXUJpcMpGjepoGHhIjjfqiv4EonIJ7KAWPZk2BELaOemqqlrQ871K6Ie0AMgeQNWgFmeDShh6CQp4JoOq3WfDKKFO@@jx3X021kA7J@yOcNypPXS6Y5DDAj3jyLD7GbIPVGTazhBYqR3Gf3FqHTmOz7RisKwbyWBKpjkcWxodI7k6jHFjPN3pOBYdOrkp6jz82PU0S2ODNqHv7nsPQTZ@cnJcEysLgSTtbHhj2jhutzpZhs@DxZk6OksZTqd4jDD5zTyP3Vy4ohKZS@BRQo8hrpkEWTHQoqk1cgwCXijyDMOuVTeicAoNx2SkeUIXikrdz/xeb8k5S51PBeQl1tw5R53ZOsoldcjtzAPlWSBcVLkUZhFQgYaJ1lauDVek4dhyDiDWuUeJemh0paWAQ/dLvmXqO19qidJPwMGiCfuBYYUTcEfG0MFJJuglLZzNANEeBVm2GNKAvmKEcwmUTeMMFXQJGkS8KmhBExsJLDQX26DNpmPaEk4UcZsSCUaIq7ThgNbNZvY8xkId0Izp4MNWnc0Io@bhMqVHYmPXm20AsVWvhovT1gXDlOLxKBiFSvMGMWgx6ST4taJGSxo8OiTN0ShVzpNA6J6ostCcFPdbl3HJo2joEb7ZnNyS1Q9AJsFlh5u3pb5RpeuB1uCrGvrEKcMO@nKOhmLDu/oAuAtJT5ZRCfUztnuO1RXYXBLQGmFaCFZQMKEfLYcMVr0aphuuhKRLUVlU5KoLiyivwb1SpfXrARaWXUaAUHwgl6eZs0vSOM2QM9EbWaYPIhLKE4NgVZF9dYEmnc/SXFebelywHqRGdo/eea8htxgEbqjh/FCJ1eIkXOcLWpvrjHFlNphwVYtv@rTXp7P2JpYXhByIQKcSIPsAgyVQJVFCQYmo5GNczsvSM0CfSxhUXJoOM8RIzsSepfm@YTOaY5N069HNZlOCZGo0@e1gaL5CZDp/YfYgl@AHWayS45O7@0dHIgp0ifg@znNUoDmC6AjCyLpCh5hcLHyF3OrGyS2Mk0TlloOmBup6O4gPRF0Foh8bOJuDbKdvuAlwTOIUhQ7OdFaIRmTSWIAgXJuk@xRHEbAEKNvbDFhlZf6f2Ke2cx7VeAUoPk0xCehO3K6glJkUx7b5XPSge6GCJgQJ9CnoJWqbCcrJNpVksPhsiBOsIFRTARFK0GgQ0Jn4TQjMk1arymbKISz4gRtil@dpVdDl4DUlrPoaOIMgQyEE0WsvydOGLJRb6c1VoOhCrGAlNyv/AlyEsAzaM1Ymu5mg7f1aQ2Z5YDNmjHs/8ejyx@X9DBWyyQw8G5mlwcPFRZTp0LVIy2uKllcsQSNDVkIHLLAgIUuIBevsA5ql/pTzg9aL0ahDIkkuIqSriHJyeUlxSDZVQnEIJoWwypiFWjEwpgcOlOZBsMZ@USagrTVYboFttsnxlUibF2VR5tGJyenS2RVhVDijvqFmzoRB0z516HRIZGrLopJHATCKPTy1rsfElZr0sRSUTqbOw6orfJjwNuz06GNFADorEMw3Uwc63hyIviAzatIRfdGh5xUpL6@xWEo2WMNJu1gwE@H5a0IK5RIN3Ot0zHVBAQm4eCp8rwgG3AkJWRVzojIv4tVlOGQJv8Gi0uD93z/qAp6v18IAegIcgIsMbeibsUaE3tpKCaKihT5WVyAbJx5bpkYRQE2vA6lrLhRJsyLDatB0LloQoH8f4sh6ULNAg/gAifIGcmI5ZxNj4Xt1Iqvmlmzgifq6sFeWJbGk6CwI6GtdigQm5ZgGjUR5E6sEY8JmIhb0ZeRTr89UuHaIUKJl9T4Y@2P2BKH2tZVojvC@qQ0GIeW81lEMiS3jvqHKXe103HWE0Wk/EkQLK8LOS0@HiQTo74NZ0TYaVxefFZAtiw7f64LN@y7pnL5eRxWePfZGQocq111mow1heEMKrsWe64KYwX63yLAea6ZFH29IiQF0IJRgUYCECy@FBaSZV9BsaZ0pChmDz09l0QQ7cJyank7L2TUzrKPR@vioUNL45fLq2BNRZ/hYpfpLbHFnoFnRAgfLPV9Tq9AtmUPNEtTugnEt0141P38taDS1R@PgTgS6HeFGIseORx9bmjs33UDi10aTr41LB93Coak70M@PiFIUFXXOHMO1YHOQuIqWPhbm@81VCAt3UQiRaXVjd3Qf10iuoZ43YF1sbSKuAF0gB9FZhxPdOcd7rUAwAC2TPVf3XS9W5uoN2JBg6ZYGPfNaxr80uoejh68hyXPTM@hjNWJPV2bU162V7svEHo7bLY7DvY6APdNyPHJMnzchqO8CFthzNeku4tLUbIGOYS@ab@A24aT@vEI1q@9YhVJf0uCxttbHbg85fPB@U14W8SJFeQ0vCgUdx1aC91oOfiq5p6@rILpPz8UFnQvGGzrTVQwpmLRYXzqQ8XHDwuqS3ZNLNKYosbG9NQnjMpZzbRq@f45OYh1qw05iNKUCMshxGKFcAoPvMqH550ktd3Nq3TdjStfAFl9XiIXKPbUM6Jbo81qVElVWPmcMRZbfnEX1rLExNlaqDo87HxpBh/HmictBdjeDIXUcxcedF1GoF4FO90a5w54XbTcyDQ1n7V4vnCwzrxHI0yPUdg/BcIiG6zH69ni0VHtLepV9xFAzGIVN1Oku5QJ9Pi9fKb1GxlmSrD2D3jfqOkw3wxVOtbwsy4HosTAFsmS5SQfKRnE/NNlzKWHqMk95HhanvdwF4@o0KFoW19CtZSnqOtWbBi6XJdu0DX@Kzzfkjh3HsT5PTQGTxH2vDuiZAl0relONXRNfgl0QZD644OGQRKe3bliB9R6BVgj4QXX3pkpfnKN5o9oUcBZyiDNEy9bVaeCIoaUNO12NJDrnTvI6UNySiYM0bLGotV4UDIYnFLEkFue103U6hqWx16SQuyleWcyuaNvB5CdOlrIp0vmEduwK7xhNoaxmF9SDgTE0qPUG8Vrr4ikOwWttoImD9zrviWHo0mTf0NcFGJnQrG18Ls3JLsguvmODYuPjOjNUECxcyRi4rkfWQ801nQe7j95ZnFwPAhwMtb5xL9QOFoYEcKEMU5zmxtWDAxVyB5uSDtECsIFgaZ8aUy98r4z4cKpDRY2HaxudjqODb9DK1q19vN6F2QNnYA@MAVtwHNnWUSkQkk8BB9Rj9we41mk0WloDvYgHy7GsRTwgi2EMx3F6K9PYx72QuIVnZXy2wTp4vXaYSvNZ40PDWjIdGGPg457jOyNDoLZ1QS0c0mDPdTwnnKr9ecdKbtRoARXh@@eF/1rdqq85/mhEX@2RNfbog0YV6FbV18kTPba2gq6Cc9y@@MIZdsTAUQwWXtDZ3NVtumP6@gD3CjOKNPpORx@Yr8t0cD6BFA5uMOsb6W6IGZMId9EZFHpArzsVkV5qi/7H@DpYV@nBOAnrDCLDDf37qrEouhtXGGmnusfG/dBEKjj0udC62J7dCt31XHk@Nv050IXFONFAJhtoR8O6vAdrCNZKInRR/JwdBmsL1lIpFV5RUBUMGQQEZV2yy8uzFppYNsseK3mD7uinvZA9r8VksC6FDnGZC4OP4L5EOksLalZK1vZg3Peu8zY25twFaQUf6zVyui51YdwVugXNDl7rMKhaEm5Yg3cbxI@xcePEQP7GmQEaTrEEzTHh1YYX1Mp47fCQZY489iRCb@28UbDOBtTMq5NbDDfT1XpiUDFdo8fG8dH0OpkM9GsQXvvQnws6zvfiMDDyadZpM55kO33g14JF5oHDsOt0pZXrYFZXf9S9CR88MvoaLop9YPq4fHAFVdD2sWr9zGthf3GseeYXx1CydcSGe/DZnJm7uHoSbSvgPdT6pn5/qSKiTAYIDtYestcS@aPT9bo4H5gerruJDDeMuSDJMSJGqmuDCL0i5NXB5@j4gXkDYlvaVoZeNUDsjKa482dKTTeNDZs@HUAM3uu0qHWrnG7MxPl4OBp7wWt1HujKnsUB1iFjZ965CcCF58A1yUCz/NWDsAujiSBIBf3d3Lg6yQr5kmk5ffKlkkxA7vKJiXLuCsK5Az3vIS4bce0VlEjTfsO5O9T5BSa3ec@hbg1coG6b/s0DGL6PS0jCNxaGdQrOOcgDD/Ap7nxeCMLJaow8WOjkou2kr@migcKOnbGrG2iMzohYlMgD6MZeuALWxF31eMbF@aJmozsWNCMwWCubhu7YY19wx/aN3L9wI/ev4DlBC9VNEl/cf/gkuVjrdJ3w6wTJ8CSpuWnt7PYVYjJtkKXW88vl0KHYf5edcHNEl6u@Js4uHsOjU7Z811mlghxOoaNYxczHw7uGjnNZr03jkfPQsR3oXUbA@IZHBtuPvbTKYHVEjPYAdxwDHrqvTeaYgl3TqTDpQRsZHahHa256k76FAb6r@dqaroUOe1GVLDK9liZMq2O4H9LxrAXzOq1xOUP3jQlVA9YTBmtrgq/rTHrFoaaltrA0ueCNHMdmT8o9ZXgpD2/mEsDa6ePNZ29FXPS9pHqvVKWWi/r4jC1dMLrswIB1ZXWNjmOx5w0LYmyTTVRrrml40gPcf07dCjkigDTl3cgrijfyirkWA5LpmebRmePVWsEcpDL5HOtSBpqrOzhpExhuWDKysGn8New4WkfOZrM7gPgJcCZNHwfHOb4uW9awM6SPtQrAQm0eGZBMFxesHU9tX5tcr0w2@BJsM19YZhRtzg7ZEjbqAkkcgnaRXK3AXcGeOaIPynnXzuDSlSKCbRr6Cw0HmhyKl/nw6pI/lE16RI1rhlsXmgsdCJU0utt4ZYtZXjcFgohlCP7ABTVc8m8aoQ2PulgxpD8eGjjvuTyRsFbkdLwBLayzeoo3YqKuIQSnrgHPiE5gY3KdsLtWYkTw8H98510JOtV2IRce/wAs6vWTypD5sWsHrzehtEPH83vm5DHkG9eYr2MbWKw8RIEXawFoSq0rBNSePbbYgEB/YdHPsEvVKIEelisIFmXLviEY9plAD@OaXC@Rw7YPSbt4jqpvdIVgLzoOlgsPwp1EUbDgvWJOb5EH4opCRWKInRRywRrDVcg9DzkAyE@OL4w8@pZG3uHBg8cn4shTVvZDuwNce39NLlva3K6W5IVRog81d2Fqjq2F6pqeL905VoS9BwciBliDbzZ6L8ALJ5eWXmuHIsPzNCVtrfaCvoa/WuC7f/LwQXq@8Y4k9gauMzSSi957x8cZ3Mfw7vFK78XY96B19JzJ2ugH@4qSXEG@we7MdVxyRUrrIJ0YoEUCMd5nZ2O8VojSnZHRPZmOjPegk0RO7b1h8oW1hXyknZl9bIWkvBZRtKGSsljIJReW/4KSbLjRe119npoj5JY6fUnstXaFBEoIWcnNrpYSbpqcviqtEDmYHP98kRT5OrUunugqad4/NWOKoqzD87HWg3ol@bWVtRxg1RSn5Zy9wWyoESgjQuQk@EBVgvnaxcpFYQisW8IHjpgHjmDsrF2ZcROAyLmwssGfG/ZUswWUlgKXkRNJGV8yFuZqosUiZ3jc88ppq2i9NUno1Bii@cRd8Nrbu3MQehwx98D2zqMn5FDzQONZAdFYgDiXLD4UcLwGT/FaN3Bx0HWBU7N@oj9aTfcVcqy5XceeThaaCs7iYldHD66M4qCNBjIsc2Ku4t06G585XL0SJEyDrZB3pkty3uLBGEGEV1/5dUWRZXrsCb4VmVmvEDBJoEmb4plZi14nBxHp69gvi@CQXKlVPTAmuGKAjVKuUk5X8u/CDby9mFzPLm/yK93gl7shvWt@6Ih7KpQbAOZv8CN5MfJ@4FjnA0fc01zjBnTclPXyDVkvL/Cb4CRmOnsVmNcLrbgSPHitpLcTw3dzo4HTMXNLIvLyBsq1w@2@5tL1B30nWDzP7KuTOh@HDfmh9sJYbMKncz5gDMa4ZHzFRFoHBDHD7pvs4DVyx/H3qe0GbSHaH7p6rtkc3R2PrrASPKP@Cnd6H5Qy59wjd3DHz1w@XKFc4tqi1e7rhCkSjTDhGYP3T3bDRB8fS@pCivNcfHC45Ix74vzHxwturjGZrNO2hMk65WWlzzzVRye5pWS36k/PXrOvAno2YHXRe22Xy/jOu8fXWydqCgN/aIU@72q2EcLpOj7dJBWNw01G88HR9weUAEI@tmJBF/QipgkwPKndxkNL2u11VHJifEAHlqGvJL4xQbGeCfjB2UDGJDfwg@9z0ChrG4BzGnHt49HAtCeBZTh3x7VuJPGhF5Z4lxxbzjkJFZ6F5hP0WBBFOzPsmzc1CeXszR1ydrHXXcITO/w/eK1D0Z01vfcdw3VXhTnSpXuh5T01uSLEu8dhgFW@e5aDg6Rdczxc5U2jptOrvNylhn01krnKA8@uPx04rr3KM6yYSuWOsRb0xg1@wyloa6s8Or3eKud9z1nl/HBs@SYKaaHnI2cMrSckq303lN7qW/VmU6yIcysexesN3OSiC3CKoTP2QLwzreTVoMKHpr/keAXf1A3PAjZs0Xauwn3XIV8w5/lcLMSLtVh6997cZ3mceIwzhXR33Ny4bqfUaJp9Lfm@MPvUsprwbHN4xXd@zNKB69jMllyc9wkPWVoB7b5mmcn1E6Hqa2ZCkc0xf3KWXdXKgOHfW8Toe9NJJDkfWnTLbmDbU6EAfV1PBp@K8OjqSyW7MCjAloysWfY2Z9lf3B9q@uKQ49JZC@G0kTdn4guahXv86M7uyfuHDwL7F7RhJ0whPB5dvctWbUVrNK4Mo9AD5KVjfAreQIO@i46gCLh7@soM2vu7Dw5DdjwAkRxQiWe8LQw0RXyXJLqupw3LkQT5MNyndBfaHprnnOj@1HCEcVQo1t@tUvPX7h64ekbUzaEXTna6VhuPDP947PaSazeyqquVneMH69jqu2Exj995@O4X7823OT0yh0QWVfhfaRmiIspXndTrTtnrTrnrTvnrTgVRviLzrZEGxdVaaQSofB22EuSdbduGznnxYHwvExzQxI45YJvLPTH8ekEiYQNPTC5/MGpxpzweH53YxONTN@mueAh7eUk2gp3o4MGHe9uDvfd4yqJpjw3cPM8@I@PXNiGZWk3Jl8k2fqGpQhSZponfryuzw@zCxBpk8yLYV16pKDOyUSN8hSfBzv7obGp2vjIAxpNhoVBEOFXIpg8@m@GudEI/GEIuCR3uFHQ8gBNsorR4Pkc12LcPedq8ODw43D8@2T15ctyQW7NgX39YCtuG1MLTQ25luzwUPsAbqJnstHV6noQFydGvROAwqReWi@AHkpaLVlsq2rxQ/DbG2bywbUmiRxtIwgzyJ/AsNeqLch44MdhhiWkFBadaVNgpA/SwBKgjBpqnaUKlVYi8KuGR5nlQrMD/6vfEqC9@jK6Cn6PDhIMDskGs7DtON0jRM8jrrzDFe7sHD54c7ZMwg3OqOTe7/qBWzrPz04Oj03g86MCiZ4DEgyhxqKtaLX4vDoiJi3FSoYdR0LPL8Zi1eEQPeIxFEDtFEpsUPmAwHlWK9N8/kmZxEfdGJCFsPMxUHJIFmqeEggfNnQCRkLtHB@/tHxHM//5d6owoQhDkBDfK/@UPuuzrH@H5VOGH@NxhoEZBbXmO2a3g8RS6QWI5RQ3OuOkSPJuNneBAjAn9kgalPDqGs/BpviQ9M4hbPFMjPGhifhYG1hzlAIsx2Vc66BkT0edBoq8ccRw9Aw/o/Zwe4XjldMMkPUGMfXaQnTsagaakF35pAOc4Qe2jXb/pmXjCBdZDzxm7VxoJ7jqnh3mKZBe/UYhfQtToh2wgs2PbZ4ehBQckxYBCxYhXZcgmzSz77A2/EDC@tQGNpGOA9k082wRJz6@QD4GCcX6xwk5AEYR6/FqUEHSFmgTU7RYCMj10iMfJE2G0j6faNV3p1a/9itSvEjD7YP4kME/kO2D7WmDrgfnrzPxUQgKV4te@dhLlZTFDeNppUAKWEa5n/uxn@NlSPrGpKKdt9ywdz8tVeCjVPMmTW5tNQdhsyLWdTQ0Q6T@fNKE5S6ncmXF30Ose9KUmz4M4mJOk1MXFRfxe6tB8micFoWuqheeT6SxbyD6fzLJK6fnpSCk0xOeTFl@qZU5bzUaLHB5@8LL9MslPzugoYAIIbO8xr@T4WKVMLrYL2dhpGb90BiU8JS/gOu0R/FPzi@6CWUNzpwd0G@dJrNnEb4zyRR7YXrwFf8opnsHFeEajLtbF7dbLl8mGpvmTKTFNc@R1u3A7A5JQ1eQxgaZ2GxoRiyCRJn1TJMKVH056ZLJr9PvjfW1qju/5O2JRLInqAmPaevil94Or@v6TJ4Q8IU@evDhaw8Za6XRCEBrUPAkdH4CElpmQSlvLx/BbZX/5w41Z5uKwvfWXHw8lYwNfj/H1yewhmo@V/K2NjVt37uRyGVVVmfnwS4e/uLu7m7ubyR828ts5Qd7Y@os/39hQ1S1V2mh5ntKKN05PP@BVOceLf/n9ePvw8IueV8/@t49e1hV8FOFxRoqkjFeWKGDEZwluheTz5E2v2IuYAldsSn/tWOh@sUGU@nbxf3zz8fOYH6ur0vsuvP3Y81ihFGNGMIAtG9rOYvXYFgYrzGJTqVargbH4P/4DxK@/C3DQZ7oFj3o@hFWYxupCjUa5jNULYFBUFdL9fz76aCGHwM@AldRoiwyvHWCIjQafK6r8dguuFL22ODwYSJAlKQxn@wPfcIhSuq3cRosJFnjZ8MJhnGYMv9b4eIeIT4/S0CekxffqG9LdLQEucSQpitpUlNvAfoVbqVpNgH6FNttsNn8bD21M0t6w7/gOMW6/v3TF3v@fcq0EU33/f@Z1RPZM3XCdDBcrbOw8u1uvQ3mz9WyqnqZX0MhoeyuWeMfZAV5zMhi7poOffaw@wA@Y1Hm5pPKZTGbnqA1RyGSCKBQmE7GNIAj7enSMXWKbMBdszoEjo0W46sgJWiRyZ7FC6zwceRZvQBtpPVsfLraP11/9p7/61l99k/6@Re//gqcq2V2zJ6Ug0Bk0lzpcO5WKXq/zdZe/aKK9DjQmV0qVktSeNROpRr11BGLtO5fxfDZOjq1ppk1bWjPZbND4dZpsPUge7fXY3LnOXOqLboEHC0wd4B1gisTCci6UK8IaIVfCcbFwJZDQOKu3BBxMrAkNpZBvCSxWYwcqh1eLZb7digmbU@BEaquu5tXHZKfOLjLY9IiDucmqhbAgQX7r87LNfea2@qJTrB5Gq8/DfN5wQZ7KXKzRkFoG7SvqYUZ3NiobpUqhokrt@vqrOo@BFw1qGMahFzuLRVeVBHQY4jMWUeaC29PFmoiqhYQETJbiviYc1BUwjckk@KvqSrZMqytbUPhqYFLbPKkCfahZQe23eVmB1rbTjoT3bbg24Ef/cEVWfG5Ql8CZBrl@bZCKklKzUv5WYV/Frvfq5QqNeppyRqFVT4vIIQXxShgO@hKidzqdF3oHJBNN62i6pvjaWJtoU83vjDuTjq@PdfyaLzlE8a4doMHNOnmn5IRYEYVYNq9sxm5j2bJqGT@MC7pJqZQtq9miki0WskVZLeWzpXK2mMsWiwAwW1Sz5XJOVbOFYrZQyhYK2UIZPz4MYQoQJosQivlsOcvFXjY2yBHjbxOSDq9m@rXXE5FyNLyowcFbEJxJDASnsX6a4WL/DFddURWSgs5RhgdIhNRIVPqDEu5p5tjLcCQGwt5F62Wq8TJFFmtLCPIML7G900oLs1kDzNVq8N@qR8YqvZgJitqapdNbT@sgAz2tN9IA8mkAUhQIBSq266S1Rb2i1ILkAv@tFmn1wTs98vpIMwLNxXPIRXqrsVVz9ugt0uYptCCZraWs7@xQWtuBWPVNYAPJdHpTEDYaALsR9FAQGCkyKCNAapEECDAXFz/nTba2gMnMtmb1WWNrNtvagv8Wfc6CN7jOtq794zknXnB2qG1@rQy6EGDWQj7VbEj1ptQMeFUL7KJURxdRaoKhDm8I18iqpRb2jij9iK1/mX8xM39GLpjllgi55mIpkorhQUTZWIqLPXv12f@Gd/PVZ3@EkiyBn1HhYheEcDEpVSbUjb7KIM49tMlDdtlgxju0ogs61B@io80eNurHkvRMJBWBKskJpVRIitj9t51eG3d6iuQZBIVg@30DGlHIewmvlgp8O61MVRLb4gtFym5/4doVj8f/1TO1XIwzHRy3Kj7zPO/hQi7n@YTAVVVWBOWyzg6WZSd//8Kq61/9wrqLi12WCeIoQRheuBiQUUySQHfkYvWtIa6bw69mCPj5s7PaB8KTXWHPGY40nyrpOIIHokLtYL9WLtdReTI2D2nbSd1NwVOB//4GFII0exC02avpQxDMm71sXm2irvqOBjo7MDqh8xx/D17gj5zo@Dt6jj9y8gJ/Rz7@yMMO/k6e42@3g7@TIf7uPMffwxf4e9LHX/OtbFap8pvaWXfShf/kxeZk84LiKq2UldnmhGc4i23Xm28BOr14lezE32rQsaB8udVA3xZ4vOW704pxplkJXt1W@WSV1U8imysn32JjLhXyFtFq5WqnplaDL0fg4kdDh3qp2U5kE01v/gE@tue1oiZxqCNbzjuuoBHTgwc4pLNlxXHjP/3Gxx/Ha7W4EKenpefATehgoA4NBFaImat6NVVQ3wKF5aVgVBh1GiT5Fh1iq7xFCJbgLTpE6biJYdK0g@9b4JFnmtsfaa5nSGeGfSYZ9ngovTBH2mgkeYbuGj6egwa1PPHPIJQUxRORNrqar0kvHNvA4SrJd4YWQoyzY30TvMQnK@02i9JuQ8JVL11T3iLBSFWQU3r6dDqn5tIgM7ppBZFKP/9EYh4Xq5FNZVORLVmXlY7SAYNJZJfIA3mgdEFsbitENog8ladEHjpKF0wG/GQwmXKPyH0i27INAcEXTH5b9tHUg1cffj0A5MLPxOVGHUXWCSRkoRpLP7uE4MF02SbvDBzPz4yaXIPECf/MePbsGc4EiAWzhYfwN/hnz5pSqqWWS0TEpiu2G8@a8Rbf5PGIVrWcI52psdF8xoMAJvOMhNAFCuk14q1qTGo2pYC01Bwlzdms3d5/dLfdllASaBKjnt5JQy@2s1ODXi14bcfq1e1mhXaUYWcZk7a2m/WsgOZCGro8FdzIfcMy7IyU/pzXHDC86xsUAa1n589A30uco9Z3fgav89DwfhMebaYPUm/p/P3mgpUa4MKwkvT@CghLBsi17aKGNBdz4Q@K8z/X3/yX9X/4hCQTjVYycTHbStArib9k8mJ2MQue9WQiEVgSW/BDB7BjlItZHY000AWYGolkKzmbMTd4JpJbDCBE2arTqCwYwXAXJBalSFMFZ3yGtkToQOj7itfneSdJIriawIaf8Vtbrn7ZrFJenJPLJMY/q2rzWZVmcyLLSWC3wQHSgk02tUs6BJ2s6vh1ts1OQ2n9xffpIeHbSRoon6tWlRRhFjWnVqu50FYsVaul0LKZSJSvX3V5WymAnpjLJZPVKli2Q7AyWCFug7xMkxppwrN1@zZLpKReXoYws7lCWsbZrGo1TCkPyRqeptPWDurjxcFjesA2sIt8jCBXCMbjEzI9oB/7oDhf4W/fTgSfYN3eTd6@rZbly8vIZTQCJ2XJqd3umm67je7Zy0u@zdOJkHIe7HLp8lKRy2klTpLQNzzC72hCWglBIbfUOk22DJ2Mmism8VPpNAf5ra1Crl4v5MClUIKIUCbWW1ZJnI9X@dgFLYVSKjI@xlfRmcSgQYMs4F3MYrQiSS6fTAAPTIKsPIvhz0V2STuFbD6frOZkOXYx41lgpVxmoZMkV0iU0uXgV9tIkjoIguyH0mw2nUsVUzugLODPm6y6kKNWL4yaMqtdGBX8OsusqgdfKcSNv8bt29kyoKYkx8jdMR4/kGlyATuugVCAMiU8mlw8nia3bnO4K9qNV6o7tGKVUp7E4lXmKMSBrZMS4FhSU3mlhDjhzB5u5wfBiFOo2r1BNjiVvvHBlZkyvoGOoOYv8r71f64LF@mSDunjRfqoexOTWPQiFmH@9KnrUSCHXYFvZKVx8YpcjOhiUw7ZfJZRbpw8GOsmDvsdPtjd2z/JqFsCian3dvcy6vGTOzEFrfm5nXpn0X60v3v38ROIcPhgf/d4/52D9/afHIK7R87nV9R1hB1I1JEsmFbYz8n73IfuC80wNGNsGO3z8fj8OfnQNNsm1Lc1hrI5fZd4RhuKNNLmxavCrZue9uGHmjuiF3n1va@8@t4vvfq9b7z6va@8@r1v/fSzb30F7h/A/Q32/sYfl/P4/Olnv/4Hr37398Dxv8D9Z3D/8Kef/fZH7Kb2H8H9XxfcfhTcC@HYzQGsr/30s29@/6efff3bcH83uL99/f61H66@v/Xl9TfG@@Yf3BzmG/8B7j9ksMKw3/hd5obva@F/l4X7@rdf/eZ/ZP@/CH5o/L1Xv/kjfASWX/32X/zXVx//Z1Ut/cW/e/Xlb7768sevvvzJqy//a/XVb/87RV58/MGrb/3J3/zpH/7Nn/4b@v8Bff7hm/xffftX//p//@v/46//NLh/CPd/BNMP//o/Qxv@@z/5Hv6/@Sd//2ffw///@vt//yef/v3X/i01/A4z/ON3/5g9f/zxV3785d/48cefrXl@5cbnZ2/g/tk/g8ub5/NN4LxJuT6vy2c/V37@KdiYpwI0AJT7y69@@6tAvL9JYuTVV36AWxDgXvP/garQMD9gtv8fGNTrZUYfGUxwf/rqK98gHyCW/hfAEvzJBx9A1/RBMF78wQcfBBj8BP3A/QPqyK7liMwz9J37fELm4aAavkNI49mzFk7nLoGmlp9@9hvfp7aYUanTqTrs8ktqKZ0C7ShVLgfdfjCLB1G@GkGNLUPIl7K2bVeDlD9B7rWUyCfI915976NX3//Xr773O6@@9zXs9IVcObObEZTXTIVCwPwbhMOAhTcJhwEh@XaaDmYKaTAblxLujdm5JKQK5ciWss15cEPq9VIV@BF4VCqpi4yw3QRpjZZ4RuPi5hqQ/RRBvZXe3pCIomWyqawGAaUcC0cq9o6cSxdTmiZx7UsJN@KQS7JglBQWUlIDXDIvXD0lBZAlRY28NkMAUTG4WBqzm6ZiUCoUzvJZMkkHJZkE0@XoDoEmKWqcUIWQaYXw5CZ0Vj38z40TjqSpcEQv/OZSaKSGIF44I1@EOyhIHtJKT6KZeioyEiatpZgLXWxAE8@BgkJnKtMTUMnBgDMB4HUHFIJaLY0RayxTYGX5q5cIzU86XYPCY2wWJ9MuIYjJHQoFYtYoHmoTFjGN8OohTtIcOtHcpEu1u5BgbXIXHdIInIJ99qxWL9UmdQT3kiElPUnfoXlCYLX0pP4S7DUKE@JxsbsvISulWjpdL2GCWEhWR6iFY03laeFo2XGmm1UEvHG52fYOIbd4pcSz@aQNRBgLjc/0PDQGxChHz3hF5Z/xOVXmIXAznQrKRv@hkd4piv0Nmm6QJCs7prxBgZH2s9SzICANCakJgiiKBG5c2rFNdsg2x7CWTtPMwCsdIJESCyWOyIFQTHFpWusMbQAfnOmXKYmq5qqglFQJOrk6hx@youuFZG5zgmvBLkggK8vB1xlnnAZhcnKWu7jUgrVimxqZgVOBwxA0zVrqc1@YWcTa5uYmF6vzWf4xnR1PSxJxTyt0xR@0PapeVQhfKPPobNDljwyLD3HFfYaj5ioWk7z66PuxnFyMcZtx@iVcwhIit9Ls3tlJkVuAVvpecJvQhXVCOuvknBhD41Y6zauQaN0BW4qiME2hcU9JrIZ/cI9RcoNe@FBzTS/DZSjjy8BLrMXQmzx@/DjIL3V4WuPS0A7VrIJ2nBkdj8cQ3ejiKoRMRhQzYiYTvEX6pg5iYBCpb/AWNxH1ZFENVIol/ASmrQ8QL9zLly@BNjjEReUA9HJmJDU1V6KehJLBBJe8acMMx04GsKxpuLJWzZU5NoZBlEKOkASlCLiSBJeQJoDGkxxbh8bIK7wScbUEmjaGhBoTExCMgSkoyKnYWl26B4jki0tWyNmiFYcm2SA/Lo@IFsmy/CVK@WToufeY7D1@@HD/0cmo1YLOhn5y1WiPXEc3PC@BfruP7jLyVcuFZKzRwLKfVFTknNx@RUYyTh/cPTo4rhCGsaDqErQcVbqyIMBLWeFio9H7WzEXJxpcg8cPDTn8MT4rc1Qk1HIWosbqXEw3UC0DOsU/3FVyZPSRfB96/TvOhCTkDM9nlAJq0kmcKIfs/KIzJniQIDu9ALgDrmcUobyY8/qFsDDVhg51cqRyzCAo1ECy5VJoKDKDUixggMfsU1xZrn68fwKQTx4TRZVFcuR0TMhU/QMyEQkBHnDkDA0nI8xobORIJ@bQwRBWzTLsvj/YxM@b8k2ZX0DQZkPO4E/NZuGp5AoZJV9sbWxYFwLCaVKSucDVmjOwXgiIk7fhItzbHHkbnOASZoRzRoZNggmKg8dVRry4L5YkIPfHvssreeALSQ4nZwJ43GjxqiLWoaEtT3NysY0vfckn9fr@o7vCwT0csJgMSLjWUzC74kCklNMduwb17RPSNd8zcc2@2DW9kaVNoRUDwlJ1wIiPc9Cx2WzWA5gH94haV6mVxe3ic6ZTlw6YZxONI8Che1zsdjhGwxVvVyq1l0quCHmrVF5mVZUDBy4lcTGztwHkRtftpCT24@1aTpHTChuAT9gkyfN81YNMZbMlKcXFFJ6HVzab5WgLIlzF4AhdzfVSrtWEgMnnFLqYi8Pj1bVJTY2uIOzk1jxsVmZh0Qc8SN93iRz6FZlfYAv7BSgKLm@mH9oMhwbl27ezOFKVzclR2QlFDZlBnW5mc1laSfcM20c6I@jbiuWKwcQhlLMV4yzDJ90amGNNLDhNly0Xx4@de2QMIQs5YInnFVVh00o5NRfjCYZGRpktyVysEQMewDVajdr/979Wg2tN/uX@AS2NRo2bACtdvANnDEPfZOnHcQ@dx/P/48fDReuN/@Fj5@FjZ@jAH7rMh8jpq/N/tbpkvfkfsFjkstUq5BjnAoFSZRBY8mD9x2999A@/@Z/@4bc@EfEKbJHDP37rU@b@3V/H56ff@odPf@kfPv0t6vJr//DdfxN4/eN3f5/cBV4wfaEhieKX6D/7Y/ww/cffwW/Tg3Xx/9m/D7w@/nTuiF@u/861/6fkb3/t//y773zyNz/86O8@/eHf/c6f/Pijr6sl5ccf/crf/c4P/@bPvkbA/pMfffXHH33tb3/l4x9/9MsQbvH/kx99Enp9OXIEM7hc/4M7wOX@xVzIEXHpA53N3woOeKzT5fgNpZxr7QNTaZDWVnj2Yx1Cb3nB9@iBy9R4rGrJN5kbX/cMqyfiIvcavzWqZ2WV3woOkK6T9wwbmXYQv96tdR2dfgW62hVN/Bo37uJi8XI5vurYeMxbLZoNJ4nkRb92TndnV41aX8QDRVxbsyB6x@lORc@fgkymO5bj1uKgYcZBrH3PdCxKL2De7To2iox2zQCtBgf0t7PZXAXKJ46c0baaLwpEaCgyyHl4K6VMFzoedxs6vIqa2TC2i8VKV9QtQ3O385U8euvRQoftvFzpix88fHDf90dHIKIYnr@dK0MEPJQLj8/ZLlXyeWjDPJ9u0BRb@Hlb1qMLGxvQARpaV4A3roPwBLXUqtD0a7V4fDurqIJSycolLijsHGF21RZySmFbrviLaCT7lmk7bobn8CucUS1gBQ6Uek7ObUnwJlD3uCgD5Jc62TX6BnYAtOaULWmENAFGCKqBsQPG/JbUAaMJxvKWZIJxXM8q8pY0BqNezyngqjMqwdogZrcGaWLJ0pjtDJJLZqBcBB16xXZsY8ZVMlrGvKA1V@n1erPURXpu4bQLgdmgTmeClulcRNaqsBCuQsYZwZx7govWAxK5CNagVHg1X@KrjercXizw1daM2xkaXVPDLyg35YvrsQogaTGoMUioSbhZxXUcv9Ixeo5rzANmlUIYkGXoeoAcP4uSa8qY4sX15AoLgSYXc@xFWOtYjn4apES/KLgqrVyen3F6gA7X6M5YQplKJnRkUSlxYGVhtcWePuViqaP3svU6UOdFrqjm8rm8mi0U8kUVpMpyrpAvAXHIBTmvqsAicuVSuTiDtilJL2P0k2Rk7yJssxV6KH1Cq7CjGhstknz5yLQuSlmBMZlEsgpSSOwlF7t19J5ar68f3EqAhP6eKtRr2XwZTFk0qVkqq6iqoGaFrCIoWfy/xqDi/83Dq/BX8Qmxsip3ggfZPALhGPQCmzzAszh8h5w4Dt1OdcfQ14TYG2j00Jw91/G8f0KYO5p9yrzumuzU1Mjrvoaf7vKGpj9YE@LJaGjaHu7J@ueCsD/sQAaRp7MAd@DhWo6zKkCRPDmEx9HBO/dPovfqUj@MziEH5LCDyCHGyf7u3n2uQO48fnT3yisfgMuTB/v3TiJrkfmGUfMRiF/cf/DgqjV45R4/OeqNHRdv7t7jJ7n5I3LCXWhcDq7lQJEzBRI80IoiE2oAZAN08dCgcLgB7nauTG4HxnxhbpTR@D7bYmd60R45tkuzwp2E@@40goy@YxD81JHRpeOe9Fi@YLhAKZY5bkRs55wUZdJ1LEvDT4r3NsBxoHmkYxio/VoWUiImfe64Vvfc7BobIGpCGmUFP9@MmeDuA5DhWB9gAqB84GGuXfzYN64Q6Fhjg4xHZK0jvNAJja7ZH4A8ce6EAbiOphG4P@8F8Y3Fy7/ZwWdpULdrPtb14FyM232MwxqxEs/v8fx9rfiUoIg0yJQy2YrN@3m@jxPGlud3G6kx6E0bG7kSUZvynkwXWU01Rap2akQpXNa3c84OquqpttGvVbx8QdnGjrcmp3dijnffKFV5XrMzwCczFQ/HKGzzKdGrIAihgu0VU4Q0jctqPJ5Ll0qUpCp/@50f/OTPP3311R@@@qPfQtmO3HVcXcPF2qjVEqqjBsqtSAdV1HIpXypn1VKmVC7l8kohn88oakYploplyJqslJRCKV9WMqVcGYSyXBl88@VioBpLUorsWjgWlmHqr5SqAHhbx@8Xb9HxGXFQ52JskQl5kdCSJKZF9jHhDYjDk127b1gAA4fVfLrTM2XWoLMmikyyRQKQNaKT2L17e/K9ezx/By249G5P5vkuWvIlWS7e4XmD@uyVUO7kHRanhIfy8T6zyPIdqLcxA4Dn0PP8AC37BZzr4HkTLXu79@5hOj20qBgfgp0yH2axQksRgtloAV2dAngeQYNguyydHM3oPlowSfS5x3z2wI/n3wmzgz5HLBgDcD8s6e4uzx8wy@4u@uzRYudZRr@All168bwLFmhUPN8HQ9@F5szzHTBi0@J5HUz6VAM3/GY0HmFu@xrPTxl6EEE8P6GhNf2U59uhOybzXpCbPGK3Qi0KK/UOtZTxx/NqmGkMlo0sWZ7PRZYclO3@/fe0gd81@uyauuytQ0nv389q5mS8f6/zzjudfr/jTnf33zlCr729@yDGTMdup98JInbacDkQa@@@qp0Op1cvKPVBu13RrJVeX2i3c5p9xas9bRuYQ4j1HHIWXH1MaNjeA6@9@@0dbdWiIQqwjVxlCO8OXneG8L6jdZhXeFEv@p50OnwVmgGoKM0Eh1oVrvvB5nkKXNrODDXddapon9SITNeMTxsFuVWlHmQIapFcnaF/L4FPDYeukxfTxqQmt2qTWlFlQ1a9BN@cqHmTz2wMt5VyvrKhbStqLj2p4CZ1pxcncUHZJgnlduoFSTxKbqugHG3wze1tgW8ore1C8SmytAo@tlWlVMnJKkkya7ZYgThyXCYEH8lGsbVdzFfmkYvFtCaplWIRBD7Ajw9iQwcHi9skkTg3tNNkErNORxuhPLTgZEoLbVZ7iUlmUmOZJNNkdVJTquzcXyJfgZZIdPEw@bGOh44QBrQPACegHeGCswSvlEs85EGSEklgRrPZjCHnIieXZhcX3sVFcxaxSglM8/He9794cnpy8gFwK5BDpmyYrB6MlB6yb7aHK7vfub8nHjwObXhOvHgPRWLHFfeQxy35MNk4dDoBBUm8D505KMehG8TxXccS9@maaJCrQ4/wsBYxOMtVPLm/BOd44JyzlCGSV0XRTcPjAfAYfbNLtFodTFqXJGiuiJY8p2JEu16vtWtDYzjyp1DEMNYXCD1jfg7mwGN5p5/1wI@e0@gXPdcZBh7tmjyD/m4SmwgC2QWpbuxmAGK7RgTl2dDpPlPTehWXiJM7tTsIptqGdwfUe8N1HZcH7ZSv9rbt2tj2tJ5xaLh45sHB400Qb/DIkESPGMlN0tzH0HuoTc2EukvseR4fjYcJTah3kstOOLsQOSCaEl8Mi3@Bo@uQc56fVXs1kngKQZ@D3d0kia54J7mdqwLG7pB2EpzkZ71nPaKSQq5KlZ8EwoImSDGFGNCStfoXQCpjoE9JpQK5Car8FKBiYgAYaoP6aMmROavqNYskBDJJUhzlqv1aA6Nf4mNLALFCEBqXLZwceB81gudj6Dzr0Nyr05hW88Yd@mUVIncUVS5UJ@CmFHPVAdS39nRSdWujsWtULbAG0wmEllirAm4BhQDmxWXi1Vc/Sm4J@Rpzq1JQlzgG3BbbtUnVxjMxgVJq2Rp4pBs5OZMvgTSTL2ZAhFALGaWQyWZyGaGIriA/ZPIZcATlC0SihJXgCeEz8kQWlYxiKJmE/MzsPktmThMy4IEiL5nxnX17PCToAlWG1Ert8NaSaTUFKOo6RNsSKPECk6liuQD3AzIyMwMK6cjQLBYhKZBsKmFtJjDQ5sl4tN9oVSr7k9EXwSshPN8upIty@kUyWU1sJGue8ZxOvdwxgUA0QC5yJlr80QbQdDDlQrzxsAG1DialqFYajQ6WtShnsnIWimm2L/tbfJ1vZeSNggJ1NqMj6wphnGVxkgEkJ27uNmqjdmAZUIdKWa1yIo7tx8gdd0xnPbIlVShL@VReZjMNDAQ3Clgk4pYkmuEulHgiHi@q8fhclU7Gqzinu8HPJ9mogk2X5CbiwLJJ/LaaL2zzIADyFb6s8hBsznExl0QOc54ie5rhaS7OxnA4QEFyoKBfcLOL2Vadm4jc/tC0TC0D4quOnygz9VORu@e43QzpmH3S03xsyyK3C6U9qIjcMWh3BjU19vGYesLi09M@MForAFihU1X@YDowQAUSuSmdufPF665QSwTfYVLLIchb3DEeFrGlPsVf8enD3cf4u7cTw30UZOct8CuDe@npwyePnzy@Rw8EmO/Y/TzXDkckulliIrarsSodOcdFDpAMFq1C3vzawalsIm3gnneSFgWxTk9T2GGpNINzfaQNQj7vbo70Vv0pezdxyyOA5ugZ2Q3SoqusDROVc/KeBgLlNolDlWvusKGq2VZDLYJYAl1XQ2ZBVVWpQi7aMbqBtw70PbmATG@l63hmwhfIdKqlhbDot0m9n96U1WnsrM0Xylm6wb9dV@RTshG/ncKPPwskdna6UVdT6fhhJZuO341nc7GzRHOznlamcYmk0uq0h8u8cGGRFIdwqpG6lU3Fn6QrpX6moqTxqcKzEifCRmynndlJlj2OUjKJLSF4o7xb2@0f7QYTG2R3r15Sp8FZD7Gnbb5UDLLY3ASUqemnO0vx6yALPcVp0Cv1Rn6OawcXkcer8dhFnMTis/isEW9xsR16KoXKTqUgsehcClwVFywhyOYKJBkjycBWLMe8RJIuqQjm8N@K78TiOFVOPO8lEDWtC9q0wz3@X3imAqOJ2U7o4Ix9HMUFUSqfx4ngmPRs5H1JLWUfHjy277r3DC7W3LjccHCSn1R5BpInL@13vwiqK9RYnDRrsUktF8ykKvW6oGypeJpXkVRACOgpBUG@rDNuVqceBRV8Xn3127nJVgnsqqyAXVXzabVeV1IghsZGrz77I9@dkov993YfkDjOy/7kz7@vFn/y579PV6DHZ3SuVs0WYxASjUqhGLu4GF1cgBA4Y375WCt2bVVdC9AkKVq5mBKrFSKVSuWU2JZiDKUgLheVZMwTYsGmhEJeSCQUSU2msiU5CT6XwYlJCVUugTVcMUGd@EKeT8b2j8y8quxsbUPJtrM5tboB1apEh42Q6LdleOUYFys9fHZJCFj0erffN1VqkqSgHb0UyNZLYQveUMMvhQ3yrFbHpYEKnlMSTr@n8LQDXA0Tr6elVJyArk3qjVl11krTOXw63vE0ZTevIKO5gdtjl51SNvyMlEd/hkGt1MEDa2gzUh96fCKVlKRul/Y7uH5CEOox1uraBsnXgV5SEuQyFU65s58gNJOvvvrbqlr4yZ//2mX7sv2BqqrlcrmgqLGf/WxrbI89o1v/GUQ8DM@mAyLSzS4S64lzatieGI050M7OtPEzVaYdjVUQdlKgGcSKDKLOc7GxjfoYCx@OXOAYBQGZ1OzbRpeOWHBnKFHTam2z0@C6CRosRUAhyVB9jh4/laxyXKjrMH3N7esZCoOk8FThRivJXXBvoxfIZwR0vir39hwUOAxBInP0tmeN3RHdVpyg8ZRWhtyGKJDC23jS3gaETpKg3xaAE0NffS0qy7JHsUZlboIHYOO5fSCOcG9DlOAUdGtK6CZQGtK0QVYQMQjNJ/XoNiDtFqRtsQht6pqgpWcBMoTljkWyQY3j3sbtplTNA7GTmFsQoAo85W1AAJQhEQA2W2SLZJPkwkynq/NDAWd4GAzundXCU@s4jIbQuoCmKHIVw4ETqI/4qVeki6CGge8tOIZAGAy2HK4GCihGpzYU6E0gh8kbgwJY5wOsIVo0cvv2PFe1mtlNEloihH9qjnCUltaDvTqvACzU5G8BSwWRKp3Gyn57mewA42maXaA6gZ2zWF2ISni0zjgO/m9MtEiRV6qKelSxAEF9sVahA8ogMqKd1aFOtmpEUYtJEmVeh7zrNFP0TKNoeKI5uSWqH4SeM8jhz2LhV5uAWZ0sjnwHdHvXsC6HlxHCPQJK2JieZOoPNMYMgi@2g8wC0ZHpHfhh7CgWFMW0aOie6YIqTFfdhYf9JbJKEqPND0ek@aDb7tQcwc1v@SS@aCwMTeCt4eFzQTobVHzVHahQb@TY9LQ6H1kT7j4EigAeBQk8cnyDZXtsn@On1IK6oZEXcwSlBE0HKR9zTE/fo99np3Fx@VrHNbTTEDcZYvRFog@7RC2TBCU0Gxdo2BG4JI1EM9wBDQpx3LGMIWTp2DDo7n6vIkl9EPzGHZzzlh6aQFeDeyZ0P7Yn3WUIls7NU1M6wWOzBaeHhwBQ4AAFZEVsfmwBHCibY6tLLMc5JZZ5arAJjcTiyX/4dYpCBpSfDGB2fgNiKyj2qtkMDoQpGRYK7iK8isxYyizE3UhMk9ffWWUj0cYavaQ9mOniZ@7PNHsBv/S65ILBFG/qcfSgwxpB5SEBdjFiudAy2ZlhcTw0LJ4UAffdRJKj9etBFIwp4kTZKMHH@GS49R2M3Mg1zggOhnDYxwDT1NtBFrAVQ2nfph0AbXvQsvDwQd@tQM2lISduN6FD0wsYvE1ukazKYUBIGYOyDAAMrPraMnTwg6hYDs/vQsWIdHYI@Qq0zmEX/PBws4D8MH5I3WimR0HOyZtsBOCw06Fp1QhrFqElv2DB1oH0TIu@AZ4FyOGKnGwk@DSATfNJnoGO4l@Nzqido7ykQq5DyhCEEKAaoFBRQUOWg4cJL3wLDReJ3NGAO@Nx90j1QPTn5@ciPWdz7Jqi4eH3wTzH1ixp1DdBHHYk3xiOgi8om7o0CuHOTQL7/J84Goy2JyjU1sq3p@zNcT2vFqxnTcR7Xhw7xzP8/FV/eIb6FWS451GCumfST@TpiWB5LaM/tZW5COmvgvQnlOIzBEIIgplkphk9A8AyHf000zvvVgOPM9ogATjUohE64um3bmgZeqHJHPWiEI6PfDTy6lindCUBQOLZjME8aVbCMOQ0tAb2kYnL4G3jnOy6rjZNUP8khkYCTkyp2EOm0O1THzBCN0Mu2FGs5qQxbS1Fn0TRoVOLVgwBI09gz3UjUC449IIkJsx/Av4T5j@ZJxom25i0mEiGTjMsDlI9rucPQyKYaRhmxs6wnftQyCCHE4WBwJDTJTdc96vXaOwQ38wG9VgLCQNoYgQINxJS4/9t7@v300aSRf@OnqKDkwHZ4suxnQw2nsUGJ@w6JgdwMrmYYWUQmBlADMI2TMbndx7ivsd9lfMa9ynurY9uqSWE7STzcXZ/c/ZMLKTu6urq6u6q6qrqHy5aF@2J59xutreyA2D2BBECRhxAt9pE09ue/4zUH92Mpq4XegXbB4k3Em981b2S3MC8gn30B4gYg@k1xLyjg7H0ZGKBQHYYIKAcBh9RNCjNU0Nz308ETR@BcVqJgMaMWEsi0ybpS36S70BcYtIzYXVAbQ0Qvve7BGjCF6FmDt8GqVaHDzMXyqiyabrADpbIpUi2k0DJyFThtWafBknDKp1WaALZUVwtRruivsNQtCKftG7eyfHX0X/62ej3YV7EY08MyxvGvqFPFXTeBxFCTheiqjgsauMKGGQ37ZEzg52rwvKp3K2hmc2sUjO4HeyCdzucd69S2uB3TR4fyr6QmCQKPissi0Xo4rLI05LnhSIpE9yv5slqS8UIsj4vIAAjF1vNkdUWerVFscgLh1isqXarIbkgJBdchUsv1iDZltVAe6qq7QWHpw3SKYYVJABenrdREIOmCeHZNw76bvx4PZ6iVqXaDNYc4gLJQyhiI59127GttzSktUUrAgAZcQVAjy@KLhjRBS@f9n/5axSTUq1R/EuyAa8VwGC0BO8brAP5TEY6MAj8iS3aB2DuJrZaRiJPRwX4vxz/l7DUS/VffvVlLlwyH36ZsyL/@11etpGy2gTVpI98bgcXZCOwVOgmi7cuaIOBHUJzmtBe4WFR@B0sABMqxhrcGKGkSHG717xA9gWe4swe@JGkqGDlhCVK6mO80FiJc4/yV1MjgrKY3YKecTFJmPtaCn1lZQg2RiFOqqcVsUkRJH0SnJXQnJglWEphNJ4OJ/chQKd7JHnjJCKrxXOvAP8BDpYCCWQi@0WKaGM@iBtR5PK636I0TnIiEJ@KVF7HBhHsg3I8weN1K/HcEwnrG6hoIuNWaiemEc5FL49JQvUBOW86SUEtK5HOJKgqvIOlFd@ZYRA8mvheIQwoo2yqFDFUKPAOtAzd/eIsoCuTgUOKmZ3Nv8rtfWtQ7ybW3Bq3vm1bm91iQsASZE/G3vXstvfTwL266YuRmP54ueguf/lZiN0dgSkrt7/huMb8XjFLcVgU7yq@zdEtAhLB7yhyE7OAZ5RJOyno/gCOAXgq6C4DQb4KBZQJI1wqNseKC9GoMC@OW3vt4gQW4XFr0t5Hs8Z8qzjfym@l8MU3eRPz/GDNVLc1bwNd7rRZtGm8tkGrwWsZRenSo8NP2NOMkLlgDjukh6ewdHiBd/WMhiDoEzPdkkIqg@5AWQGGDSDqdyUb1T5q9lTewiep3kOljKgh5NshCiX@Bw9vdvNoh8Uj1jkmxQeQeNwFEgblpIdd9sU2K@2OwB5hKdi1BzoSOOJojsHp72e6zxgy67/BXaW@oHEMr9UVqLjiqT/s1AXD@I/rYfen49diO5d7mc@9yGskw7tUEcFc5sVOsF0BkdSHbXTz2c3vGMaxO12ysx5s5ghrJ40ALXGKyvF70MucG2cycYzSaMRefR5ezuDMbpxexjDqTo8cRi@viSKoxl0juUCrda9nXc7oT5exL5Ev8LoRugMAJj/@RW/EMag6fXl5nGWgFQQUsvFwzrYS92aIN2f4lp@@Oxq5t0iwLhpdmB5YaezAHmdsmiKMEhJL4UL6/vjam@OURqsxArQv8arTrk@GCWx@XRgZMmEYIwBFhjutsUkvggm01x3ZqGpl4hCAhjQKKASga73rrnMvDgYh8Zk4CNkxFYphq5HJujPDpbkytlG1BbkuIDCNClXTcIcBbr6pNkSjdtL8UKpXBDy/q9feV8uVsjj6KJpvKuK49u4jueKKN7XTcqXeEBghelw7a9arR@fNGrxIlBpQM0EfjNLZR1H5/l290miIWl1U3747rQI0AF8vnTWrlYYlqmfHp@fl6tlrSwAEcVZritPq22oTijVrFrWqqhlBPVE7EW8r9eM38LN0VD2tNj9SiyfV5hk2dgKtlcS7Ur1ZPT4/LdXFu/P6u1qjIrBjRrnaOD4tVd9WyhloH9oUlfeVs6ZovCmdnkY6WvtwVqkj8qFeHlUAy9IRbI/YEvWzXK1XjpvYoeDpGIgHCJ5aovGuclzFh8r3FehOqf7RkkAblf84h0LwUZRLb0uvoXNG6gGqwLgcn9creBKFlGicHzWa1eZ5syJe12plonWjUn9fPa409oVxWmsQwc4bFQvaaJaoaYAB1ILv8Hx03qgS3apnzUq9fv6uWa2dmTDIHyp4sclxCaqWicC1M@4tEKlW/4hQkQ40AJb48KYC7@tIU6JWCanQAKodN/Vi0CAQsal3U5xVXp9WX1fOjiv4uYZgPlQbFRMGrNrAAgAT2/1QgkbPqdc4ToAXPwKzGopzLRpOUT0RpfL7KmIuSwMHNKqSW4hsx28kzTPoYKsJaEO8rs@xx7rQ1l99deOgU9iqtBcv//nnT8e1ckUk1LlhIvhwDrvOq8jBlP4Ndhr/I/wMHQD0nMvrQQfTdKLE7ldjoWrsDSxMkGBiaPaFcc9ZtZTdqMLGRqfzvtQp1V83Oh3TekzNEBoP1aAsoCCs3VPKlH3EWDK0oaFQWSgw3Q9ChDr8BsXBvjOzBDsiU0mm/je0uU7sMeiK2WzPkdXQFIKAlVgKe/DMHQsA1sOlkaywGEweNElSD/0eSnagiikFPtPtwGvsORdyPfhn8mvwgzcH7QWszixKZ7MDZ85ogIKqmuFGyMBE/0j7DmhfJMl7jvPTIJXTm3MmPTODVzChh6SsQ2Xnzmg0SJkPVL90BpHq6Wh9QhaNmio7sMchBaxdIGPyOZgkmZDjkplRz1L4T2dOf0yFDVvQ0FBCTZEJXipEqW@4eivXRrKyoRAkah5klPnelr6vfkAlN7e9sx95/8Z/z3MLnQbRvxQ2vBbVa9OfN20uABOMLJtAkqG0N2azWh0Qy0ig9AvfQsErLMRXSOFefeXQvg4kAUH22h7pbeJuPBsudOxhHX5dL709Oj85gaUTsd15tftyb9/wDzG/t/jvR2yHPDzpDHcK@zjIafRJmyXHIPjQTNHc8QP2JwbOZrEghnCoQaOXaDXz72liIYFTSpAsdYDd9TCzwgTNIAlnQndLkTnzqaH4NXZmSgZIhbpqYm/G9oJEfBtkJeIBeWiKd97DqC3wH4TtT381xf0OSQaSLEY@r8C5xhNe9xJYiU7a@u71hI9BsEgmofiYD8V9GuDFUyJfkMeI9EvytjaKINjiQON8pWGnmoDE0ygWQuqh5N0NTbwjq61ULuksFt58L/kNHj9KdwFyHrC9eWneADKe@DVRBw4UXdnploTcxpA6PKJWLR0ItCCYEimae1JV9c2s2mwgVDCmFa1TYcD7vlU22iQqwsm/JUHfZk5FUyjC2ZccK38D58Z1R0LZV9ZY@VvZ@ATD8k3GTLVbvw1DFfnoWwUVOUNk@ip6EPw/kSYx8A9A4wToAbU0l4pHUZKgMq1AfSWiDG@VEUOznATU1F99DMDc6QNz5XdMWoYW5EqAJJCjs1QvPpITST8VQwBkchM9C7T523MduqwadmZQnf6WMGV1tMFMuuNpSsi9Qm0VK3DTe22LxC5L2W3whylMMswKrcFTqCr@xorbJc16UJkiqrx47iUYnKmsqdlNPM8IJjxxKVIkryZ7wFk5OcvUOiAPrrQNp@efP4FYerfWIrgpNIej0NovrWqKUAD6EPFZ7SfFFrqiO3I9J@K/whceNMmnAL33LXk7oHQAQE8DdHFCOM97Ql6858xvcYMYMXRyfAigidRz8r3ARvhYIhAc1HJrZoC0tK3e@tgvCPtbDfvzCceY0M@CUCUy7GMiMZzgzYnAM3Svs3hrLwHl0eO6zSyW3Wy4lrh1KJKHzRKyPoZadl13BqKjjf0GHK3h0syID9Lo4Ey865n0BoH9bDiTFgkl9EMzc7qWnWiB2wzHbhBq3hDkhjnaXJA/qEtjx55IB5HhIr0nUsC8ikcPkYXJrWWxlRepg@DLAdCEnLyIiAdiD/OVUSkmqHTAcoiCQ89XLmCWuNzOgcgF0@/Wnf2Eez@KQJOe0/P9vDSQ8EINUnVCHjPdOXd96npk0YChQAuIT4k8G9Iu7e5Ptyh5wx79UrITCOj4KhH4GqEnGPXk89vxmVRCxYYCxpWtA/PtpWEwkUrb0tHKd73Kb@8SKnEK191aZYx8r8ImcZG4mPhLSkFeb/pciY74xOum//QRn/h6O6f43MPZA2/Qfi5FUEQYZVa02a6uc4Qfnld8GDqznm4TBUmmZ0/R/EaqjzshXlSmQ@lE0bXnnrMEDaCbHS6yBKOT@rt7NekcuyN7MHSHNuhpGF6x4BUPH5f0iAM2mLm3HkURcxYirVBvGTyTNVweauNv6bGDP4ODTm/uTFP6Ech8tixhhgXUYugYH89a/f2K@HsaPXH26@zsBpX8OvJG9mvvCnTT/bV1X@TjKvNpAQKQC9xh5HSGjskd9HksqpbcaUo77lAFLu8roOF4KdLC1j7frcX4WyARHfCGMFbIrBx56J1AzWwtxq3ewuqRR8fMncO6VXYwbtVL0WvLxgyZsIp8h6cQBZF/ldOqUvrJ3gK9OvBhuZ7c2y//ZOwBga9AP/8ijlviGIGWuL6cDbAmkzIhfbYAF3JnHtIaTSsxrGLDAexCoxDQziIKNfx5uY4adKoIQpF0WljhSpyRKVB8MNlFqgNLTmdJl4AnRdIkRwEUQUp4t8tahnV0ZtX9a/R28Iibw@wyuDAdS8gpDel1pOoClTC7Xgjm9FpHmT1UH54x29uPHbUIAYuSgCEctLSTqYSSXNATmy9cntOxljuDxTgRoZ48lUx6c3eafCT11q4dsefccbTumuuI9CnCbEXYLDd7RNriEh@X@0YUnwjThClGp9jAQ6i@0rPP5lEiLoodnG/FzvIBOqyjWXAm628q/nj3eO7jpniDoaVqo/GnFOGOLl/7/vtWBzreWb@CSJisXnVoxejgktFZ8qMGKkImn0qPpxBxn8Q9Qo8eUA7b7QHt9PFZS9ToAbxyIFOfQi5DSE90g7fHDq5L034GOpIy1fmUv0j5AufCWtJRXj59iS6b@IEBolTspAM7FFtwg8GK8BHFWvRTHXQLzONKBE@H7LOrPJ8koj7BKMZBGnfYvbfVWabz7X2GtPAhgVbBN5HfA0m@wmKtzoKgrJACpngMKfweraxNV4/v1df2BcoBBK5Nn71rPIIHaQo7Y4otwAb@0T91FigDB03JmqEZFZ4IHVoaYC6AljIYOayuovQ3nDHHw0NKTiNQIPh1Cv9syRroHL2X86mNVRa9JRYxJbl5tpmYB42qBAzFv5H8ciqyqEuKKwBw5GVtMD/yAAGdxAh7PBQYOf15iPNCiMoxgorFPE5LeEk@ZoEPScx3JKossLOrlcjFlfhWh5GOBQKCRXyZABGQWeKLBFBgo4vFRSvxMr4/QQkQiBXvM8VhKOSohGnojxwTkHLk5cxgRWnlhZWTHEwfd3bN0Eefv@nrtzntay76FejjY9hK56NfX@VCX0PNbm@Hq4ZqAj1MvdXQRyCFqSPsrwpf938GuQRqDuRKwj3QlIyQlCF9vzCHIWiZoLdlfvTEAZo4DpWMoeDRYVw6T6qiUr86HLAWcnG/351dJOnIAD3hv7q3KmZDYSIjL5IXE3K0Z@MuK4QksSZwq8duoaZL3hRoOCGPE9BvlU7r9sX75smJrgSLy6VyNBo7s91cLodMfKmHEii/LTQlDd1suHS2fz0aZae3f5@9v8zS2o/pp0eeW1AatANDApPCy7izAcfZIA5QFEungcBj98ZBXf@639cDWvCEEgcPho1Lsq9YT9AGNPSdXt43OcD@JNhg/4kdxP79U/iz79ZmQVNCUcdQUBuod3GTUKdnQB580UffL/@kioDhwqy8mWDfMouHn3AHwTgxGixyBjXRLCTZP/HGGY1cS3zAPGRPE2RRiVQ4OdEr5LgInjAiUdDFaAQcZgnnZjgKzqc8LKLzOoJTG5OK2lFe9hhpUHcGlcU0lWj9kIBtBbq8hd3cQm9fSyQGCVO63j8CLPMhoP2o0mN7muoSnaKFYauXMzh4Aoxe5K1Y3SdUxCSbmKTZw6WRqPHoZn50h5MUdN0kWUBFBtDwUk/WFPeJm7hY5PtIwxzDkDjRTXKPqnG3/3VL49ctizfzfv9xqyIFVfDAftaKyHFlX7cg0hkAzUA5/YCeGF35jzRM65NIIBQLOBj6tLruYIUOVjCM593iz7epUqkknk23tkSpdAQPmOjnqCTK@OLoSJQxiwr@/qa4vbu7z2tu2fwEL4/UyztxBDD44t3u1awMP@FbEQPcYLsnLfJZtvjM2n/WKR4c7nvZVumonc0O4ImvaMqW5A@8uyl7RD9aP/iFMplM9ln307Nv7vbxd6vcTj67bD2btpODfeQyIEPpeu5W52k7cB/NzC6NDd4FtLfkR6r0bA/zt8qqQqVHGNuzn2B1KYiNrpfdkG89jsOlNXaj62jvnQkmQgEVXoVwRFV5A0Pkx/YSzfEwOl0HHfBgv6HkreQHyvX5bEUZ7ieuVsA/VdkgBKTMeuMAaDzhWEInuWGMH0gPJ54zQQv4Dcm83D3DsOHvcN6R/Jv9QV6isHmREps5sWmJzUSC/uCFCpsX5rPsEK/p4GL@VQvB0QK6GQpvSIIe6Q8UuRght2E8owBIhKTCoanw5Hp8icZnpf1h@KQMX/cGxhO6XJJNJHTIhFU2Pj2b3MGwfIISdwnjCYUz5jH3BwsKHanFUGPaiYo/vigC2R47AgQtj5kgBReaxJM@qMxnfln1Ro61QbGZBBjJWn99QvMeX8Be9IxiOvMRXQqDRin4kd/i3rjPwbuENn7h9gME6ECF1ckchY0kN5J41kG5@v1eUjcFxXjq/ZPMx74OS2eOFYPm/1NoTECfnuiEezahd3SOSR@Z/omhf7yiNZXgshRtzyczhlZlfD2aD6cjeeZFJMKR81u745mEI0qAGA5HUBdWZxgZCjDzwa1DYcj6sHDo8VL0XOw6zwSZZBWng5nhkyONCNkfUjC3f43MbTM7REwUOzAPEFK@K1/fHo48JPlcZWsd2LNLzLVAmZnFcM7nZmTPw7w6EYzdvo90hiCTy3kwn6ErG9OZPRjbltg4c5sze1mFbQskn3k3Y0IPJ8k5IYGTTzYd1z2FMPdIDglRxO8KeQ5h9PZoKYPNeWxxNGgwaEjVVJAJGnAShNiJKOn8GhqrCB0Drv6MQdBRXlm8/dNIucTSyoueRhJS0AX4h6bZytQxVAv63PEnTsJgVP2ZqXhBVrrGjXZMB7@wkmMqb9U21XTk@aCA5RLbx91p4Ezs0OY0HRkGJyZ5lt0XvC/ifKbEHuyNJK//yb/MB/kDECuQI38IJbiRmS7cPstsxpNU6smFJ4PjN/R9BIXnjO@Ln7WRVeVZOYWDjykp3/lkyItlZIcaMu2BCTOiSp7/AKE/sgeA3/LWXiIrXmykvnuaNVs/XEzam6mLya8Xv5iEiVyS1S6bFhvyMFutWHKuwM6YtUI/lVeaJ@@UFxeTcIGLCbl18em9JAEgkk21fsi2f80CQhcbprmZvdhggoSGDDHJ3t9eFsFnV9DcCGOR3TCemJumGvzUd3lTwN5Kf3EM@YXJfwELpVSSmR70nFkfQFEMEN09gIpd9tV2bmc7vwOa0MBZpGfONe63ae/60lmAKOGhOgtbz8UvIW4IEeJu4dn78HIB/RwOJpgAmkbUkwkt5BIqpzm1Y/hsBXUyzBNQHqicQhJgiIvpl7Hx8BEVfksAy6mylNGCXQc17kvh/um5Y2zH9nBdi0aHMEeilwH7iJAJNY2QJeOt5VBTTZckBZtlxPGVA4OMQGB4sxvabjFxJ2kprJmZ5D4K0Rg1M8LcvtE5ujJFQzP0mRSmkk9F/vC7l//9v2s/b8w3DrezH2bwd77x88beqw1@hAf49UL9utk43DjAYnt3G8ss6MDw@PK//w/UP/w7wMEvywP453BXwdpbbhymi1Tl143DPXjIb29Du//3v/4L@vCMNTbMbPOsYwlCbF9R5NieEO/Cd1HFXrJamgyWlTwuLAiDPQxBN4cf6Bi12H6VIzPdhvSquEH3n2F/7vujyC2eHLPm5CrElgzlTwGSEVcoYgNpBqlcKPpC891QbhvIvAGa4p/PM3seaAD/lO4cfpO@68ZzD12GnrFaBAOY4hZBn@eHw9x3Cd@9o5BQPiX7SoRE1U6uta9e7AM7vHOd@bAb9pJQ03XctW@dywzyYcbpXYNONfFG7o@z7A2w5Di//SrbR@N@lvy4s1OClJ4uM7@AICizkYBiSE6nlpjBCLhj@AvPmKMEBPoT/0xKZecAKXvqdNmGFc7wBEUazXKlXrf4eBi7kwlE6RT9CwI85iGRaTW0yPOLCdSs1QsiseUX5HKk85qIzTtyjpVJR9LsDUsZbEGAoT6gdVD1J1OaDSgIiWrNAAIXydi9XseW31LGk4QKPLeMJ1fOaFpMkG8Y9AavKQMJXdKfxcy1UNJDtCCk07TQIayxM7dBRS8m6A3q40ELc7yXgM9aSTem1cUna1@WlVp9r3iCZ1r3NH3LTd/CiKKUELTj80yQC2ci9GK8thTRVDlzOnikFtswtOapFFizDP1BDDwelmofwxJkdygCEqgWdEd6lenDZpEuDDxy63DMHpsWOQ@YsREEP1qqBHBW9SyDshO2m@HGYIE4cydOAT2U@To5jIAoqqQtwwkJQCufVeywBEN9qE0dRlMRCjtiyW1pAvshCRwYSymABEPH400t8ME2ePfwQUs4WkKfBBpeEiayVL9AyhYVVMNRoKRa3DhqZmynanWFn6ynL3MB0UVp@CKRy2@/2Nnde/nqW4wZfyJ7Gw8GK2VQC5he2QCDJOoUKNn4vlhMJBP8ChN6rTaJ0OPA4gEcunXdmoQVPz4t5nMSWC5BsG4pMRVXl@ZKAhlAnDkZ3BFAR0nNEqnUd4UWdqx90TN/hf8SlqrNDIemZns0/MVm0mvj8I4DIijN0dgZuzM8HseF2abMLphXH7YQ/qKXddx@3cE7qdDXldkeGjp1XQxKmLnXgyudOzJs7RdNmDBA8PlsWSAN6rXDkaKkU2tYoSwqDQ5VLfqiqOC1VnuATrm4JaDMx8BhmsFkQC9/W3qa4uxIwiaEeR4wYhWPEDXXUZ2diTsnrqiclaOIyUxoQ8@Hm9E9W0G4g/0QwFdqJ5j5SOtuE6gLU2Ige63WJIsN@qT7ygUuh@WAK5DpMVa6i2m9NKqotZrkhnnqPrLkiReHfkK7oCqMI@IVAzOfe5iUKq5V9QIJohZCaU3yFzHLP8/RSRbgpA8yzlPk5URB8xF9O/Q8yuctG0uY0qOUCsFAenwqEQcQ7Ta5BHckV8ARpccKpbHi0ebLU8llEi8c5QH2NVUntuSwL00FFDXOmUV8WmD/q2fHlihX4J@TD2ULBeWj0j@w337CrPX45iW@@YKonqghIIJKMxz53KLP1M8YogTMkrM4fUmAIC6@ZNjAeiR5IwUr1RNJe57UrdDcbgdcgexqSyFcWUflJMGsKWQDeSKVdzKdyVyLUqEvsPFqdaXZkoXVtGAT1/0TW6PJk6BVHxKT8hEgtqMg0gpEwO1PAoZnD3SSvG2puyjGrp7E83SIZVmhArH9JAtkD/PsWsrcxxbbki22CziO9/EF8e29vME3loWZ4wHeePplvJF@PHOk/y2Yo/LncMcLyR0vCrj2MHdMujOHViSK6KSkdm4Mx1wuaQ/u9IaDIdqH@tpP7ETO0gDQgkcXkdkUD5LPYd/WLCciFf9hK7ofoZPQ9u6e8YWd35Gd3yngmkuPZed/aufTv3Hnd2Xndwu418SMvBTtZPjrb9fjQCRMhV/EDi@Ku1zM/NKe7sme7hVwN40Z5j@8p@nfqacvZU9fFjBjAh84cArX@7mZJZFS47haDdwtMioDcQqzAsZzpYm6F94xbYn@6Nq7KqK0Lr4Y/1cS/1e4GtFTHclqazHKvi7P6ikHy7NkydflYZAV94T7K0O99P7KDSvQR@QGxYs0GbZmUlEBgdzij8FpUyaQH4PV1998Hoszr@2UW4kzw2oKNGuEeTOY4iz5UmGVgPUJM/IcLWnHzfrp1v9iMoztn2QUGiCPQ3uL9wzJnURXwXCs@LXsjNYdhN2QOkeIVSQ5Cdm5jPb22eXJ@lWNEltE9sV4JYGP2jhdMmagcjQPIDIZAW0ysr7SqtA1V6kX/Ab6zoXiuyx7/EVc@q3k0m8Loi4Vg3WksqXBT/JioKdt7@7etwdwrQz@wQmYs6D8PbPq/wWHC6vuH6U@Uqfz1vG8DS1ZlKHn6eYyAsuIcJnSNZSZFfDKmMkl@h@895NPbRtatmVQVjzDOH5bbqDtwr7s9pz@4Gr440/jiTv9eebNr29uF8tf8gnDUMn5UyZnLVTeN9JMsZqvOTFLRJI2p7WszQEINMwn2WoSNoQk8/mk2SoUttumwPk55nxMfD4QACARdeKN8J4kcrPws4fTULIHQzS216Ojf2@OMedAstTIHl/2bLEoCPS/Tuctgd5g8m0XCAkkIjtMqgur59Q0TboXRl45kdQhF5KW/lPv6mwwrrJ9TiQSEiX4WaUDATS2@EV9C02LTC5tsQnMx1@GvbClhG0yfk2ZWg/VAsmn2zttswBk@kBfkOGv7NGcTwRTv5i@J4wz9yMJcOs85kUOd5GcGQpc0JA@oA3Q75gpmSM45eL@autq6LvWjg@jFYBvhwqHaKX92IKp74fuADCYCu6R645OcXxVC5akhiVeBZ0JMiFiWPMbe9T3R0FlKx6yU2WId8J9pByySO3QwEQIIYnR91e6IJj6Cpt1paXYr4@HDYDxJbkrrIDS8cVKKwVWuITW0FBOH9o0ovV4eL05pxOP6UTAnC0fCcoRHfCb9n5DfF@rw@jf2LMhGrbY2paHNjJOBubngBz@53IyxSYqkpNrexfmlQ@ZZpi5glx8n9ahnFp9CXqvfIkN0LqDHcArc1UXcDcbUHbDh5F@BMr3TOcQhzJYZO8T2I589lZMnd@TQl0yiUhL@TFu2oW5G1l7hj7GqVeRwVZ0wOm1h@RSL9osrwSfX@E4Y84x2ANmNruTbYjz@RAW8WXg00zCDTmM6VIWJSFiYJybPzqBu1eWuJQ/ZH4diam2eCBtKE//lRkkGl/TOQWsxe4YW@IlnrkTQ/gQQYDDGZA341ZEbMz/mRXb5vruQinsp7cqWEa6HBrU@O661zoCuQf7GZRXT7CH6Ov4CiGG7TALrEJQS610Hca9QX5a5Ww8kup0MPdPp0OpVjodlB86nSS3wsKEJgRp916ULnvXs/TMvhrb9uTv2a7npfG67encMLpA1oMDkayclZMYauV/ykyXMA7pzbSQefoFiRz4xkgkwlGmx42GaBzXq@@agr4ZNCZddzRypHggZaTarId3hJaH3bkSm1jKU7/GNqYVMuhSSnHseQ3ChXuIg9vpoPt/p5PynFFfG52N4An@e9N8eyqalHCwWWlQPsRGTFGEkcEASFJPEfGDp@XacfPjuwpQcTw6NA7UHyh0SPUO5sP5yDk8yPJffufNlygKLKcOaIHyXZZeQt0sVz64dHtL@NMb3gj6VEyoo//CzAFxa3jj7ENlnbaEYN915wGCWaiPQCW0LCOoKuiVQZCrlWuiIOweHtmAIKiUB5xUHgaGDPtLkXyRzAw90utTZrhlefOJlEaT/DODLSYtkbzdSsZs/eGBaLwpAS1fn9aOSqeY8etdpY5pLNeNxeWgA0yDEixdy5AMf@XwNHcSEiroy1xKrNGP4VLfk2gcfvcx/G5NN@qV11XM57gecyZpUXzKFfJ34U836FMV@4UuoaBvd6sYrEHl5LT0@l4sUKlb2ffoK1qYY7@uaap29rqGKSgxdea6Ft3JADSNQQdbjiGv@oxNd/CiDu9R9FYtH9XK99B8MOLORBvFxnB6PKqp49r52frFQboI58NQNgwf0fPmu/OmEa7pL1YwYWidssRCW6q0qSV9UhbmOvhHpUZFVE4p46n2iXxdRs5YQbfE0uJFBVRQWjsdD0QXSyUqRDGmEI1rpqtVY5cj@xL05@u5s49xoIVPd9PF/tydygecapjjt8CxrqlPdz1nYO5fGJ/uEtx2MQEMnTj8dMeL1cUkyVfRzFMSUX0yr@DtI20aEWKUK/Xq@0pZ0aOhfQ6VBKJVj9VXn17d4ayLcXMaxSj/jCWzz8SMUGplE6YvRHmGkCQQTBkGw8/odzWYoVdtmiY5vN2/dHHzg124N7z2Cru55/s@XSQiK80xSEtfHCNJ12PkBNVh9C77E7v7m3WO@oKw6/d2CMRa0EovR5i4Av4b/e4dvDDkiF6687k7TlNaazW8XCv0HSdT6LMPACbX@tr4MaZqtCdfQu4Vkj2Kt9Q0o9TOJ9Vj3uQbIPWX6vXah0ZkNVzhS3s2c2/Pp78Pa4qcGjd4khSkVUwg3QSsa8OeuDBoFaML7Ob@vORaWrGYQjyUstSFweV0ZkddgjAxs9t0EWHw66smMxGt7N5O/iXJhrvH70qzMJ3qWOmPI1TQu3voFOKctYTSaP6Hc9cptP0vSTSdBX8nqq1f8yhl@71rXiDANCvfN6NCC5Kf7qXWKY8vvozgq9uv3rVAIKQW1rCHxNdHO159u2eF7w9Ho3WCr6/iLVblZSlRrqmpqX@LdfJyvdKonb6viHL1dbUp3pdOzysRsXmGZ0M3Dh9ky6ZmzgAvhAD60QmV1nBSUyC6GFpBcXB8jkXBbngajjajvm/QtETf4XCQ4TzpcVlDt6j6@X4m7sSJbUk1EejlhbgUT1HQUC35axKtV/QlXOcWbwctSrjyQOjXpBk1vUMx6daTRMMMB0uQty1et4r3WK4ahEfShsajFKJvQFkEnG@bq4vQ1WNrb8fVlqSIHBWCRHNlRszz4c55oNitdm57tXNAsK/qnkQQ7VoZaDQF8O7HrOt6fzhi0ObDiIFW@EdTDaNaQpQzI7r86gkFuSCs4xLZcItmQfg0TAa9/cNZUiTVWhhnatKurCiwrD24njxmiurnqMFB6uIpKvHWygQ2H5rCx@5odcjya/uXnA0uQae36P9NfxeJPYu37rvkIv743lpzqn8fIPOe4Y5dCiObQvWsXHlXOcMracQ/Kh8/1OplNAk3oluDvPg9MoS@JzaZUD3d5qwbWFUFLkbZKOauuicK5JgrMXK7MCtwJMhYRjvxIjhqZPAc/AIP8ubl0EmxOoinZYLMGckwNVZgMJuI1XWejpm5QwhuZ5UfKJPmfZOXq@P1FCt1l4@sm4@pi/npH9v29pr6j23/RVx9ssyysUjaqxAj/rNcI0T766U@RGiAWTdA90/yleEzf98BFP9@I0jWr68cP2V0@qMG8dVfg@j/3@XskZV34iqPHll5N6by/LEt78VVfmzLL9cyrm/qXOVeS0Qtdp/BztLu9teK9CetSMrued@iFD9oaPf7a9j@zGEjy@vnDxwZIv8auT9z5NgW/PlDh9bQv0buzxw5skd/nQSHhsjIIJKBNIofqu5R7MLtsHsF2jUJQPjjfSIkWjQjKATWTCf1CDKZj20M1ckvUwi/VNf7UkZjpx20ekuztVAe65KxCu11vQ57b7wvnYq3tXL1JM6DY4VAnvOHTeltUvR9sgWWXPxI3jdxRrNZh03Lj6aqiAWCToL@mGN4f@wkQ7@klireJtuwbD/G1Zr9Zf165iN8n6Xn7u3MxfhzD29YUiHeY3uucaBvRymV8VLl09p5HQa23viMid5zf5@Bdadr6cgmzi/h/ht20FdrYJST/MWVJ3W0Z7IUYgaft5LxDtqaqZNiafoj1w5Qo7eY5J5fr5h@w22kv6aN9OPa2PyaNjYf10b2a9rIZuMaWbMslStH569FVjTe1D7El6Ev3hVeEIW3O3VnjjNZt4SF1zCo8/vweqzl/E@zAkZ2CH80/NkRqfSg/V4uRz@BdOLfY6EvQtrg8PDx6AwnKoXyo4aHLkD7A8fnc/aLuDFiqvAxxW9KzzW2@LPaWZoM8CFDPN9h73u26iZ5z8MkgdIq77nXs65@nkKpaXGM@EuQmTa1Ejl17w6GtymFHWg5xAfjvFS@Bwp9FSqTKN8NEs@37Ji6BQMe20jgh/s1jfherivthBYmJZ4Qd15M4jeT@L7HLpaBt3NrxQG43UoiRsm2YkgiRCyYDR1QOp3GKp@SzKjJwqc7kAkJFDzerccjxgM4FtdYr@eVkut9mVf5PmjeXEvQlXGOhRcJOfGBr7pOm2vix/yJIHM0h9hDniPR5RH6RRKFe4/cFqFUzuHaImnpkTxrycnHaYGsaYkFLEH4b9yC/2iX8diJ8LgBjncM164po8uEjbXziJb7kTpc3YiZS7EwwtXiJDY8@QWCx1N7zeao8fVKMCJxhNQC@Ix95TjxPs6nqnFs/cCpf2R96CvFIpjYeHruT@1k8m7N2sBzjOr7lycgVSwguhkXp6jjdrgONUKCtB1P0gX0zPUlsZAWr5Qy107fKWWdC6Cvn1tyJ54iVc7cifMFJOS/DxIxhgPDE9j3N7FXbCSaUsZH2yRWpEmsoAAi/4ybshMSql/L02F2XYcO64glUa@UyqLRrIuT87NjUT1rNPFF7YQ@nFbPKjGnOsv4YdG3P0XwlqJ2O0j9@OiVNwyIN8R/pVWYtHlFcDn20tONmN0f@we4/IE5RrQPRWvFURbFy3jCqhEqPEyD@IotgN0OFPFh@15AQ86J8W/ABfHUuJ8vHtQGNI1g4grvGpN64WbiLEAH8ZLmY9eoVmGHlyXcq3@jnVITEGJ3yvViR8xiFCctr7HnqSsxPmPgmIR0H3yMbCHVTHVLhrF23lGB/Bq7X@DmJBeEqIdTaHgi@lvpCFbd0nGzUhZvK803tXLD/xRx5sU43WiU7mromxaCa0aC85OXzuB6Eo0xpdC3Se@RkDl2NjasNUO5muJDXjPdkQs0WsGIbn9Pro3WOy6dnpaOTiuSNNGAvYXTlXos5vztTO35VbQHrMaqiFu/GOz2s2Qk@8urZBQ9HUKkWzQYkXch3VrWixRBQpvGQ5HnHC8OSPvx2rKpIDGOVi7DdAhS25gGZhY1DOQCke6KdF4PSH@qRR3TdToybTq/tjA90sS5palm@0lpjf8JgdyPDK/MyejKXFxwZY5iK9mpn0Ki94MYy8ThTm5XxoM/FBfOJJapjsJB/mLqjpaDkQvP8AAUz/acm@zkejQycMvvDfv98CDoz4ffbOONmE73yhWAzf8H)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ajfqv)

Python sources are [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python).
Windows versions ⩽ 3.9 cannot be used because of [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue38755#msg391018).

Based on [this polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/139664#139664).

This answer adds 10 Python versions:

```
                       New modules

425   Python 3.1.0     importlib  tkinter.ttk                  3.1 whatsnew
426   Python 3.2.0     argparse  concurrent.futures            3.2 whatsnew

427   Python 3.3.0     faulthandler  ipaddress  lzma           3.3 whatsnew
                       unittest.mock  venv

428   Python 3.4.0     asyncio  ensurepip  enum  pathlib       3.4 whatsnew
                       selectors  statistics  tracemalloc

429   Python 3.5.0     typing  zipapp                          3.5 whatsnew
430   Python 3.6.0     secrets                                 3.6 whatsnew

431   Python 3.7.0     contextvars  dataclasses                3.7 whatsnew
                       importlib.resources

432   Python 3.8.0     importlib.metadata                      3.8 whatsnew
433   Python 3.9.0     zoneinfo  graphlib                      3.9 whatsnew

---   Python 3.10.0    ---                                     3.10 whatsnew
434   Python 3.11.0    tomllib  wsgiref.types                  3.11 whatsnew

---   Python 3.12.0    ---                                     3.12 whatsnew
```

Answer #1 is now considered to be Python 3.0.0.
#431 3.7.0 is tested on TIO with [3.7.4](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBP/yC0oy8/OK/@vqlqUWFQOZAA)
#432 3.8.0 is tested on TIO with [3.8.0b4](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPoPBP/yC0oy8/OK/@vqlqUWFQOZAA)

The code is on line 21 (with CRs as newlines):

```py
try:eval("2?2");print(349)
except:
 a=9;b=2;import inspect;e=not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394;s=2-2
 if~-e:print(e)  # if e!=1
 else:
  try:
   for(m)in'importlib/argparse/venv/enum/zipapp/secrets/contextvars/importlib.metadata/zoneinfo/tomllib/'.split("/"):__import__(m);s+=1
  except:print(s and+424+s or+1)
exit(0)
```

```
('/')  ("/")  rSNBATWPL, alt: ('/' )
n  e    psPILOT
i  s    alphuck (golf)
0  2-2  Whirl

for m    for(m)
s and 424+s or 1    s and+424+s or+1
import inspect;a=9;b=2;    a=9;b=2;import inspect;   Moorhens

spaces at the ends of some lines are for css-script

lzma  venv  because lzma module compilation fails on my machine in all Python versions
```

Nial fix: `#` on lines 43 and 51.

There are now 12 CRs on line 21 instead of 5, so ><> code needed adjustment. ><> code doesn't break Affine Mess because there are even number of
`n`, `f` and `e` outside of `11..11` comment.

PowerShell here-string `@'..'@` starts right after PowerShell/PHP code now, so Python 3 code is hidden inside of it.

Relevant for this answer languages that consider CR a newline: PowerShell, PHP, Python3, Tcl, psPILOT, css-script, SSL, ><> (official interpreter).
Note: [gnuplot](https://tio.run/##dcwxCoAwDAXQ3VN8VOiig849ikuEoIWSlLSeP1J3tze9k@rtfslTsjbEGDGHyg3FMK4jDunaAjB9QKpQAaFyIaPGyEl4gSjYTG34n6xrD@4v), Pyxplot and [Make](https://tio.run/##dcxBCoAgEAXQfaf4YOAmF7Usgg7SZrIBJR1BI7q9eYHeAd5BxdUa6WIYww@FtdfvvGxsXcIItWeQBhQIvsBL8ScjeGHYFCPLPUASOOeUu59laou0pdYP) don't consider CR a newline.

As it turns out, we rely on some weird Python2 bug. Python2 [treats CR as newline](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#physical-lines) (like Python3, unlike [Python1](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Xz@/oES/oLIkIz/PEEor2NjYKKioFxRl5pUoGCrE5BmocxFSZqQQU2Sg/v8/AA)),
but the `# coding = utf8` declaration used in polyglot [stops this behavior](https://tio.run/##dcyxCoMwEAbg3af4IUKWCjaTlDxKlrSeGpCLXK60Pn2UQkenb/uesSy1brsumR2892iteeUx8fx469QNgTdJrLgjSG8Bc4pUoEJRaUQsYPqsiekGzig7a/yCRLI0l@2Af@t@ba0H). `utf-8` doesn't have this effect.
I discovered this at the last minute, so for now polyglot still relies on this behavior – Python2 code is together with Python1, Ruby and Perl as before.

Answer (score 3):

## 450. Python 2 ([Jython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython)), 18950 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPJdSD6UTHl/RHJArsBEKg33iBAstnsaY76JZI9MxaARhcKBaCahSp0VYEEmmTHjNahK1my15YlW5YfI8vrvfKVN9Z3Y/d6HCvvRtgbsV82HPvJP4CyHfeG7ZD@ge45mVUFgATYPfJ6w3HjFlBV@TyZefLkyXPyVR3dH/z0pwm8yBPXnvZtNyCB6Qek61knpieSO1OyrVt@XtU4DkPteP3x0HQCv8IliEKIrTv9sd43Sc@yA9PLEt80Sce03VPwVwnZHDtj3@zWwaYR4pinZN8xrC5AIIF7bDrWK9MDvxwhd037fHgeEMMdDnWn65ORZzkB9c0T8kQHS29sHBO94weebgSW64BXYSGJ4oKtRMhD1/NNgOQapu@7CKu8EESRybs6pDeyzckVyIpCPrBMr0toLkaeyfKiqOT9o3v3rrpq5POC65B7mMMrXjmyMw7c/eAq/DzZ6ZuOTlSxLKpXPQuAp8C0S3JJvupVhKoyA8u4mk6J7PR6lmOSh1DWq55lYvi@4BueNQo4qEpyz/KgmvWwOomhO1BtWKkbxByOgikRGCHoth1Xsk90n4z9sW7TcM542DG9KKAf6F5gOX1yagUDEgwsP45HQ/sj3TCFrmlbQyswu8S2IJLbC6EAaKdLjs3pqetB3YcwXceeQkTTsHoWRonyAQDxSgUDk8EZ6lMgHCcAKiE68SEbthlBS3MJCH/X7Iz7xB0Ho3FAIG9dy9c7NgDtTEnX7OljO8iSDvhBlVD304HphFQN4EQAceSyXL0Y06yZM@LXu10iA0FDPo5NYgHWaLYqRNPAnbgeYA1CRTkKgVECZ2U0J1DDUGc9t0Lysgz@e7EL5la3fTfMzGLW0NOBRkvrDOE@8dy@pw8BG12T4vT9/SfEN1wPbHBjWNawbgJj6AHZ3CTJvUd3k6QeV4vodbi4imrkDKogEXmSE90eA4XM14QL9ePFsTmssuRaskKSgBZVJrkcyUH7LRE1D0hS5DIYgBGomgJ3gaglklOgveWJBoE1FRp3AXygQZCcDI7lZBbT73l637JNBr2P0IvYfCCaCk85RzRoGVpBY6H7rt1jQQ2akSLRSqRQJMU8KcKzTMoq5ASTzUGjycNdgBsgliGbAEjVINOyyoDN2gXQMdLiLunpQ8uehinQJAySV0gRoEJ5FICulgAKvDUNbw3uEkJbvOZhBwOojYF@AuAF2zpGdmbGHA2rWIKXtLEhUdaJvJkl7w8weUAtIDVfIkVIvgAYyUEWAPNqCZIHTy0PWYAQWr4ABdPgLrDC@QPTtkNQAx9B0RIUZbihNEXATwlqDGpClRHRRbjBDhxVBdapAp9UgfWpwK5UFcwaJgvhsAoLUP2FHEtmoPvHkBBLR@3SSoHuAMAoWAvIJhVEHECAmiSAfg0zSnIaEg9kHsoEeSkWCBBGSSGlHCkVCeC4LBOoMwXyhZSlAIdWID8KAgPaUIA4FMiTAjWgAFBFyxNurgIUDf0hrgZxAV1KDuLkwAyVqRTwhnhAMQokqUCaqlqeES7kTc1DefMapWi1ADVeBD/Amwp5VYHMkIzVEvhj3BLgsIQEX0xmGSJ0xAPUFDYRoE9ABlSPQuFCWDCrxZCgdXs00DvYH7CYnR5GLWDTKSAaIaqMxYN3DrEJWYFaVrGFQPZVoAqNtjB45@LkbQWANBC82bUoU7exY1FiDBWzlEhf6KNghjalQHM0mgaD2E1lbi4wWwsYptnXjWnsCS0zG3vOXAsauqqUP88AyTl09YEbu2PfngGJDTmVJmWeWPbMrUTduqbe7Vn@4PUsrzmaSMfUA8c6nqWSz2fnkKrPeRTQY8GpqM2HDSwBurj@AE2zsqhFDDNy4wpayLKi0Ox1zN7Y6ZtCuTSXP@oTjL0AOqNZmmXm7Fn9PnTsMzhKlhaTdq4z5zzNoa1p0OdHjohdTNOzoMu/TYwBiCyxZ5nBL5dnMDQVYUz1DkoCAohw0HOUsa/rWRPSuW3QnmaWQY3iyRhYoyhwZWXgucqliUxKhTnaoJh7VZJjlo1XS3zhWk4qSZJp7oKD/omJpfO9O3SCH2DPhn01ki70xS6VNGYsNeVEvWkakLYoGEBPbaMA1TENHXtt7MNM2gdHcKxAJJAIyJame4IyL@1IF5LxaWfb8VDEBcmoa3oewbAgF/tZ2i37445vvhyj7DXLVw/6eRPEgZ5u2XEGaN@iB1RogHfSh/Smi9nuee6QdkBD7HZt1x2tEHGgkz9FQPfdU3OW9ZkMoI9GNkha4G4yQQ8yc6pTYZ1K9vOpsgxBJIwHFQ4AaVIgoVieaVDch0WH2BrIMotZrBC1fltDKHfmRDANGguIJz7Gcca2XQHZyDSIVpe65omELkxMWxTPMA@R4AbiVwiio4M0jjmnuYgh3VZFKhIeRTXru8PForE@dz8u@sBCYco@1adQez3obs2JPgSdgaBgDi2XDIFiWA1iTYBygcXaJ13XSQYxlFMPBF8odFwSKlwjTgJraILq5EIUrPEczTT2@DRnnSmQMsVWTqS6EsvJFUSJ3FVEMYfcnANrLCAidscGYg3TthxKQSBC@agXeMAqmRsXeKTZ1OH2QAYcheqhiAYMeIhZm9MyfNbaQ2ndoBBRrjUdHxQXXyQWKm9A@X23B8R2akHZgWFB1BlsgyIBURA7TURD5CjKkYCGxzaxiDEaEXCHTgnI855cArHVfWGRV@BpD0DtMMaeNyWTEdSENYRQgeH2ekC9r8zRAECQYZcYUwOaJ1QypR5/4OgjrutSNmOMFgs7s62bEMZBdWb3yc@TvgnIB1G3h8okEv6sGKMRLQhFiO4wMdjRAV9YEGM0pcjhErMYPdcV0b3rmj4lGdc7jhkAJuabfdpAoLX1ZixpiGI90KpD1ZEu8J@wkSF8TJBbWhhMKqSFd00HGpABtAlNHyoRa3aH9EBPnxNuUUPRDcMcBSG1uJSpWc6cpvD4HmoK1FUIgYn@gFvfJptXaAeCxvQzJ@Wi5oRZH4UKjI4cNxwMEKj4ESurjL/Y02vJQ4iTK6nzzzHMQg6e8yvyMKINA9UmyirGATIU5JGWMUCOGCDPoZI4tDlvfL344DafvDckQi9OG3OjAPPhRCl2wnyshiHAbV8HJI5shFVfcMCgCw5vAK37wyWQ3TiTdnfeVZR0EVjjm4AOXcddAhWQGcPFIIs@tC4oMR4i79DtmBhpc/EX6gjZ9mx8Crsz6ElHI9eDlsFYz5SOQdAqm6OuUHVPxT1GWiR3FjtY6DiS2O0H2BdChJGtAy1gE8OWCjqXDvwCWBlTrYHzuSzFuQzTVk9hhfk7pR0AIyboUR3HRLVN96YMCBQPOmlIaEoszwNmeIJdBeuJoi5FpHQKPYPe7SJ/RXTQdn81cREpenfcsSZX9XcDHcUXPneie6SHqrsHogc0olSy5yfTVepOY8558ZI7CiQalT15CEgDiVDlqZ4vYldxDxjN4dQxUvxCE@OzhB8HvRKfBgNGZJIaeQ8Uhqu5QyUCiWZ4DO2a2qqkD524IMBTQDeaE/SQRPTQPZA2oBGCrlkudzs6OQfu4RFhsssUkkgxUcRcnJbpdOO0QkRgXubLK7IkfM@gBmGub8MSYHBactpJLCDwLTFBI/LgIElhD4sOVOZjflS6YY5jh473kRQTSNLkLBaBoQNI0cxYIIJYhhW0Q6Hl9u1IfFmr1YDYQKYCttlNz@u10VioCJwaAotUJgkTEQP3MMC2kUpDeTHwBcsNCE9AqbU6OQsGHrQ4ar/gIBCglXOQkiPEhvX8yDoed69WtIOOGIjHVgeik2UEfJUDEYC1htpNWE0uYBV03yRiFYkX41PQ14iXumKF8mEwz/RRCK6FWZmr4RTmIKTVpShiUUO3GUHvTg07FAmYCRo740YdyP5xOAQWM6JsKBNEjfZaS2VAsDkwOOTJztH9WtgWmafUsZzKgoPtGrpNndcxOB/FfbB/52Dn4OfbS2DYVqdy1UGycqUCdrXjidB3xlJOVCvr8zBmgO@2b4aNERfD8FzoTQR3MicqTQ3oXCYROh8ffP4qSkASQnTQFMCM9xWRhoUBoYvr6P7gSidM@pkMJBlHicISYZ9EMGMDZh399Sg/T8avXmHlXc3UKHTHnNljnQGIHKV9J4onoucVASzy6vRYj0jjgixqOTi/MTPNh4zy8y7KzlczQwXqOZJ59/G9vYMaBRuOrgk0iOQHIEvpXlcEmrfHoIgvCwPsD0wGyYizjKNUTfO6FMGGsYDgWd2SFfABAGo8oksEexgVzR9A3nevlo26CkZMAdROIVyVK@flIeOzZnQuH9jFGaj4LutFqcess4qdlvZYse9it2Xk82YxV57vtoxZmt15oHQ6AfqBSG70wOvYF9BFnEmRoVgdZv/wwbWM@1SIBFVAiHLm20Skafk2h9qLYJGkL@2CnubapvgB5Xg84dOSlIxmFETDpyroXPi9iRWk5DR7K2kIC6nv7Oyrd6PA4WA2Hc@gSgNq5NgzeT2cIjR8oBHHtd2@SzYgDpMOowRBbFpZzJ2@61yrIR0dsagJnGUE/ovDN/oI@hrrFVUfaax5pZXNV@qOfwpcWiloiCSKIQpKouHFF/qJDuialftw/4t70IkoeVmOzTK9AAVzcSi60GTMuVIHIkBCYpifpQWMpyWvtfbIQ5ibF8RCh4wujrgz817qSDmmKC0NvzRL77nXMP7CnV4hLXBhpAWGOZTtP3ryYP/R3sOdD5uBms8v2HNyuQCIg/Q6IAuJA4Y3bK0brGlisRBcAtqGh80LuMAYFJRonmnse8C4RQwisgysoBo2oZt6zx04ST99tTCn6Cu8cAxGQg@x8bGgYURQtLs2KiMem/DG/hzpZxAEI78iSdDKB@OOCEqr9MJwbb0v0XjQMdi2pKDqsv8YRzf8ZTEgM/7UZDHYEBeIDlM6jqjbQxeUFzptjqyBpBh4OnZlW/0B6MI4t256aTGmYFoaqQsaAujKUlw2yoCpDXAbvqN64hlpv6OoJUbXiqzmJD4KttD8IexazwTVKQW9FaAifcVKmrebt8kUuDRCugokQcQNOsjhE@wLbAKCJB07RT0/Qg7lFjhqiryC4ujlGMd0gUtJeTlXVAp5CdQyUNNAZhVw5E0Y6oExEAJXAHiC26PjBnNU2PMN3emJG6EhyizIfbegqFrjWbPptEBAb96mecMZ68a01VBa6Sq5HmUjDJ@uAvUuFA9pN3IA2qVGIE36Jiv4WVe/zs66Om1dXSIFw1HY5wgj8nAHBKlXLvDrrjnf9jCCNO8pbSyElTDwa2nJgJCNUTl8IKYkaFDQ0wLpSZgvAYReFA@BcoBvzUUgs9GMWGCaBgPgHxpJ7VJT@rqEi85ayDUWs4JDw@JoCiyPBkKmLWiYociDJjhiEDArSVCBUOJB/yTLAh1IOPKApY@gmtiA1i50BKDO@TgUGWAXjHM2YzY2jE0ytOKA547wRaILr24SLqLQAPjyB5/2Qjix2CaSOzpSHGDhimQXRhTJU2QB0JdPSUBHGromqvG4bOKpY6EiInLUV4CuK7neFgNvjfCQ1uUP/uTy49@@/PrHlx9/6/LjX7385I8uP/m3a8Jr1DHrm5lmUxCzjRbhk9cyf2tPvbVz59adEs0hyJOQ@f/7F371b3/tlxbzviTdH330tR999It/80sf//WnH/3ooy/9@Idf//EPv/LjH371rdJ1/tsvu8Z//dgNkzzFoZH5BMP0ILnBAHrR@yC1NTZunZ6RtbU1iL62tgU1sba1RTJkC54CPNeg39wC3yw8t0gDfNdIi1y0ONBgfbJktE@k4@eiqRuDNnBLw0xpaRG6vLPzyTkZDBoTEdr5MW9s8K0LOrtE@wKccWGZ3sVKO6QrZzDv70H3zWyzzK9KuiE1G3Kz1TxLNbuZdPNCyiot0LLbFj78lJpuKKIogBvylpQknpUupDhvExoSAonGwJvljE7YsYU8qEszgr9nTaAnAlYJhDQ/Jk9ZC53cwaHVL5qjwdSbDxCPV4F8imPPs/UhuIwG@d88f3nF4s@LQgs6ciQxsnAgFuKwF0oaoynjixzLaVNaWJ4U9VgnQm/oBrr0vgjqhjjX0STXkpIgQB9CfRgkWuyHlm@AaqE7pjv258folg4dYurgejQYA/veHVgjzjQGLlD6NsAk8SwJIhknfAQ2bRRF6xoi3NiskWXgFAP0xnTpjgWVT1svHcVQaNInum1147HsfGH0UoxTq9I4RMaErL7jeqYAiIAYHF2nRJfBcfVoNnefjhRd45WhL@0CkO9aZpAl92xXpxh1HaCFOWrEuZBZfNBnIcqB2eVshwg9EC1EVgOe2ZU2ODq36XoDYJdQGpyyUeM6GoYekuuPumIwgahcCjuoeU@mDYGQdkq6qqoWjHyvEvkhLQCyB1A1qMU5oBJGXoICnumwavfYMEqk0z56fHePjTXQzgm7Ixx3ag/d7hjksFDPODCdfpbsARVZjjsEVupE8V8d2weuGzCtGCyrRjKYkmkNx7ZOx0iuDmPcGM9wO65Nh05uijoLP/Z83dbZoE3ku/P@Q5CNnx4d1sTKXCBJPxnemDaO2y1PluFzf36mjs5SRtMpPiNMfj3PYzcXLbRE5hJ6lNBjiEspQVYMtWhqjR3DgGeKfIFhV6obcTiFhmMy0iyhM0Wl7idBr7fgrFHnYwF5iT1zzlFntrxyQR3yOrNAeRYI11ouhJkHVKBh4iWXK8MVaTi2nAOIdeZRoh46XYAp4ND9gm@Z@s5WYKL0E3KweMJ@YNrRBNyBOXRxkgl6SRtnM0C0R0GWrZE0oa8Y4VwCZdM4QwVdgg4Rrwpa0MRGAgvNJdZos@lYjoQTRdy6RMIR4iptOKB1s5k9n7FQFzRjOviwWWczwqh5eEzpkdjY9XobQGzWq9GCtVXBMKVkMg5GodK8QQxaTDoJfq2o8ZIGnw5JczRKlfMlELonqiw0J8W91nlS8ikaeoRvNie3ZPVDkElwNeL6balvVul6oBX4qkY@Scqww76co6HY8K4xAO5CMpNFVEL9jJ2ea3cFNpcEtEaYFoIVFE7ox6skw8WwpuVFCyTpClUWFbnq3NrKa3CvVGn9eoC51ZgxIBQfyPlx9uScNI6z5ET0R7YVgIiE8sQgXFXkXF23SeezdM/Tpz4XrgepkZ2Dd99vyC0GgRvqOD9UYrU4iZb/gtbmuWNcsA0mXNUSWAHt9emsvYXlBSEHItCpBMg@wGAJVEmcUFgiKvmY57Oy9EzQ51ImFZemwywx0xdiz9aDwHQYzbFJutXoZrMpYTI1mvxWODRfITKdv7B6kEvwgyxWyeHR3b2DAxEFulRyD@c5KtAcQXQEYWRVoSNMzhe@Qm51k@QWxkmjcstBUwN1vR3GB6KuAtGPTZzNQbbTN70UOKZxisIAZzorRCMyaSxEEK5NMgKKoxhYCpTtLQassjT/T51jxz2Na7wCFJ@hmAR0p25XUMpMi2PHein60L1QQROChPoU9BK19RTlZOtKOlx8NsQJVhCqqYAIJWg0COhM/DoE5kmrVWUz5RAW/MANscvztCroKvGaElV9DZxBkKEQwui11@RZQxbKrcz6MlB0IVa4wJuVfw4uQlgE7ZtLk11P0fZ@rSGzPLAZM8a9n/p0@ePiNocKWWcGno3M0uDR4iLKdOhapMU1RYsrlqCRISuhAxZYkIglJMLl9yHNUn/K@UHrxWjUIZUmZzHSVUQ5OT@nOCTrKqE4BJNCWGVcRFoxMKYHLpTmQbj0fl4moK01XG6BbbbJ8ZVYmxdlUebRicnp0skVYVQ4ob6RZs6EQcs5dul0SGxqy6KSRwEwjj08tq/HxJWa9LEQlE6mLmRLFYvz2fKHnR59LIlDpwPCiWbqQAeaQ5kXhEVdOqAvOuZ8PfqVxRWRM9Pv2eJN2reCmQgv3xBSKJdo4F6nY60KCqXHVVPReykWDpCCVTEnKrMiXl1/QxYQG64mDd///aMuIPg6@gfQBeDIW2xoQ6eMVSEsw@xCVLTQx/KaYwPEY9vSKQKo6U0gDd2DIul2bFgOmk5CCwJ07EMcUg9rFogPHyBKrkxGDXPOZsSi9/JElk0qOcAMjVVhr6xHYknR6Q9Q1LoUCUy8sUwaiTIlVgnmhE1BzCnKyKDenKlo0RChRMvqfTAOxuwJ0uwbK9Ea4b0cBQsh5bzeUUyJrd@@oco9/XjcdYXRcT@WQAtLws5KT8eHBOjow@nQNhqXF58VkK2Hjt6rgs06LemUvt5EFb4z9kdCh2rVXWajDWF4QwqezZ6rgljh/rfYsBprlk0fb0mJIXQglHA1gIQrLoU5pFlX0GzrnSlKF4PPTmXxzDpwnJqRycjaiqnV0Wh1fNQkafxyeXnsiWgwfCzT@SW2qjNUqWiBw3Web6hV6I@soW4LanfOuJJpL5uYvxY0ntOjcXALAt2HcCORY8djjG3dm5luIPFrw8jXBqSjztEyXOjgR0Qpioo6Y47RIrAZSFw@Sx9zE/3WMoRF2yeE2LS8sbtGgIsjV1DPW7AutigRl37OkYPorsKJ4Z7ivcrbH4B6yZ7L@65XS3P1FmxIsA1bh555JeNfGNbDYcM3kOSp5Zv0sRyxx0szGhj2UvdFYo8G7OYH4N5EwL5luz45pM@bENT3AAvsuZx053Fp6Y5AB6/nzTdwm2g2f1ahut137UKpL@nwWFnrY6@HHD58vy0vi3mRoryBF0WCjuso4XslBz@WvOM3VRDdtOfhSs454w2d6TKGFM5WrC4dCPe4U2F5ye7JJRpTlNig3oqEcf3KqT6N3j9DJ7EKtVEnMZpSARnkOIxQLoEh8JjQ/LOklrs5te7bMaVrYItvKsRc5R7bJnRL9HmtSokqK58xhiLLb8@ievbYHJtLVYfHnRdm2GG8feJymN31cCwdh@9xy0Uc6lWozL1V7rDnRduNTEPH6bo3CyeLzGsE8vQI1dwnYHiChusx@s54tFB7C3qVc8BQMxhFTdTtLuQCfT4rXym9QcZZkKx9k9436jpMN8OlTbW8LMuh6DE397FguUkH0uK4Lyz2XEiYusxSnoXF@S5vzrg8DYqW@cVzK1mKukr1poHLZcmxHDOY4vMtuWPHde3PUlPAJHHDqwt6pkAXid5UY9fEl3D7A5kNLvg4JNHprRpWYL1HqBUCflDdvanS5ydn3qo2BZx@HOLU0KJ11cjKU8fWh52uTlKdUzd9HSjuxcTRGbZK1L5pkIYOTyhiSSzOaqfrdkxbZ69JIXdTvLKoLWnb4awnzpKyudHZTHbiCu8YTaGsVhfUg4E5NKn1BvFa7@KpDuFrZaCJi/cq74lpGtJkzzRWBRhZ0KwdfC5Mxs7JLoHrgGIT4AIzVBBsXMIYuq5G1kPds9wHO4/enZ9VDwPsD/W@eS/SDuaGBHCFDFOcZsblgwMVcgebkgHRQrChYOkcm1M/ei@N@HBqQEWNhysbnYHDgm/RylYterzehTkDd@AMzAFbaRzbVlEpEFJAAYfU4/QHuMhpNFpY/DyPB9u17Xk8IIthDMd1e0vT2MNNkLh3Z2l8trM6fL1xmEoPWONDw0oyHZhj4OO@G7gjU6C2VUFtHNJgz1U8J5qj/VnHSm7UaAEV0ftnhf9G3aqvu8FoRF/tkT326YNGFege1TfJEz22qIIuf3O9vvjKHXbE0FEMV1zQadzlbbpjBcYANwkzijT7bscYWG/KdHgwgRQNbjDrW@luiBmLCHfRGRR6QK83FZFeavP@h/jaX1Xp4TgJ6wxiww39@7KxKLoNVxjpx4bPxv3QRCo49DnXuthm3Qrd7lx5ObaCGdC5VTjxQCYbaEfDqryHiwdWSiJ0NfyMHYaLClZSKRVeUVAVTBkEBGVVsovrsuaamKaxx1LeYLjGcS9izysxGS5IoUNc1tzgI7gvkM7CSpqlkrUzGPf967yNjTl3QVrBx2qNnC5InRt3hW5Bd8LXKgyqtoQ71eDdBvFjbN44MZC/cWaAhlNsQXcteLXhBbUyXjk8ZFsjnz2J0FNXBQsX2ICaeXVWi@FmulxPDCuma/bYOD6a3iSTgX4Nwmsf@nPBwIleHAZGPs06bcaTHLcP/FqwySxwFHaVrrR0Aczy6o@7N@HDR2Zfx9WwD6wA1w0uoQraPpYtnHkj7C@Mdd/6whhKtorYcPM9mzPz5pdNom0JvId63zLuL1REnMkQweGiQ/ZaIH90ul4XpwPLxwU3seGGMRckOUbESHVtEKGXhLw6@ByfOzBrQGwv29LQywaI3dEUt/xMqemmsWEroAOI4XuVFrVqedONmTgdD0djP3wtzwNd0jM/wDpk7Mw/tQC48BK4JhnodrB8EHZuNBEEqbC/mxmXJ1khX7Rst0@@WJIJyF0BsVDOXUI4d6DnfYLrRTxnCSXStN9y7g51foHJbf5LqFsTV6Y7VnDzAEYQ4NqR6I2FYZ2CewrywAN8itufFYJwtBwjD@Y6uXgf6Ru6aKCwQ3fsGSYa48Mh5iXyELq5Gy19tXA7PR5ucTqv2RiuDc0IDPbSpmG4zjgQvLFzI/cv3Mj9K3hA0Fx1k9QX9h4@Tc/XOl0g/CZBMjpCamZaObt9hZgsB2Sp1fxyMXQk9t9lR9sc0HWqb4izg@fvGJQt33WXqSBPptBRLGPm4@Fd08C5rDem8ch96Dou9C4jYHzDA5NtxF5YZbA8IkZ7gFuNAQ/dNyZzSMGu6FSY9KCPzA7Uoz0zvU3fwgDf1QN9RddCh72oShab3kgTlt0xvRd0PGvOvEprXMzQfXNC1YDVhMHamhAYBpNecahpoS0sTC74I9d12JNyTxleysObuQSwdvp4@9lbEVd7L6jeS1WpxaI@PmFLF8wuOylgVVk9s@Pa7HnDghjHYhPVumeZvvQAN55Tt0KOCCBN@TfyiuKNvGKmxYBkeqL7dOZ4uVYwA6lMPsO6lIHuGS5O2oSGG5aMzO0WfwM7jheQs9nsDiB@ApxJN8bh2Y5vypY97AzpY6UCMFebByYk08WVaodTJ9An1yuTDb6E@8vnlhnFu7IjtoSNukBST0C7SC9X4K5gzxrRB@W8K2dw6UoRwbFM45WOA00uxctseHXBH8omPaLGFcOtc82FDoRKOt1mvLTFLK6bAkHENoVg4IEaLgU3jdBGZ1wsGdIfD02c91ycSFgpcrr@gBbWXT7FGzNRzxTC49aAZ8RHrzG5TthZKTEiePg/vvOeBJ1qu5CLzn0AFvXmSWXI/NhzwtfbUNoT1w961uQx5BsXl69iG1isPESBF2sBaNpYVQioPWdsswGB/tyin2GXqlECPTxXEGzKlgNTMJ0TgZ7CNbleIpftG5J28FDVwOwK4SZ0HCwXHkRbiOJg4XvJnN48D8QVhYrEEDsp5MI1hsuQexpxAJCf3EAY@fQtjfwn@w8eH4kjX1naD@0McNH9NblsYVe7WpLnRole6N7c1BxbC9W1/EC6c6gIuw/2RQywAt9s9F6AF04uLbxWDkVGB2lK@krtBX3NYLnAd//o4YPMbMcdSe0OPHdopue9dw8Ps7iB4b3Dpd7zse9B6@i5k5XR9/cUJb2EfMNtmau45JKUVkE6MkGLBGK8zw7FeKMQZbgjs3s0HZnvQyeJnNp/y@QLKwv5SD@x@tgKSXklomhDJWWxkEvPrfsFJdn04veq@jy2RsgtDfqS2GvlCgmUEDTJ05ZLCTdNTl@VVogcTo5/tkiKfJ1a549ylXT/H5sxRVFW4flQ70G9kvzKyloMsGyK03ZP3mI21AyVESF2EgKgKsF642LlojAE1i3hA0fMQ0cwdlauzLgJQOxcWNrgT01nqjsCSkuhy8iNpYwvmnNzNfFikRM853nptFW83pqkDGqM0HzkzXnt7t7ZjzwOmHtoe/fRU/JE90HjWQLRnIM4kyxeCDheg8d3rRq42O96wKlZP9EfLaf7CjnUva7rTCdzTQVncbGroydWxnHQRgOZtjWxlvFug43PPFm@EiRKg62Qd6cLct78iRhhhMsv/6qiyDI97wTfisysVwiYpNCkT/GwrHmvo/2Y9A3sl0VwSC/Vqh6YE1wxwEYplymnS/l34QbeXkyvZpc3@ZVu8MvdkN41P3TEzRTKDQDzN/iRvBh7P3Dt04Er7uqeeQM6bsp6@Yasl@f4TXgEM529Cs2rhVZcCR6@ltLbkRl4udHA7Vi5BRF5cefkyuH2QPfo@oO@Gy6eZ/blSZ2Oo4b8UH9lzjfh4xkfMAdjXDK@ZCKtA4KY6fQtduIaueMGe9R2g7YQbwxdPtdsje6OR1dYCR5Of4U7fQBKmXvqkzu41WcmHy5RLnFt0XL3VcIUiUeY8HDB@0c7UaKPDyV1LsVZLj58suCMm@GCx4dzbp45mazStoTJKuVlqc8s1UdHuYVkN@vPTt6wrwJ6NmB18Xtll8v4znuH11snagqDYGhHPu/pjhnB6boB3R0Vj8NNRrPB0Q8GlAAiPrZkQRf0IpYFMHyp3cbTStrtVVRyZH5IB5ahrySBOUGxngn44aFA5iQ3CMLvddAoKxuAexxz7cPRwHImoWU4c8e1biT1wo9KvEMObfeURArPXPMJeyyIop@Yzs2bmoSydnOHrM33ugt4Yqf@h69VKLqzove@Y3resjAHhnQvsryvppeEeO8wCrDMd9d2cZC0a42Hy7xp1ExmmZe30LCvRrKWeeCh9ccD13OWeUYVU6ncMVeCXrvBbzgFbW2ZR6fXW@a857vLnB@O7cBCIS3yfOSOofVEZLXnRdJbfbPebIoVcWbFM3j9gZeedwFOMXTHPoh3lp2@GlR4YQULjlfwTd3wEGDTER33Ktz3XPJ5a5bP@UK8Woml9@7NfBbHicc4U0h3x82Mq3ZKjabaG8n3ldWnluWE51jDK76z85X2PddhtvT8vE90utISaPd120qvnghV3zATimyO@ZMTbVkrA4Z/bx6j708nseT8xKZ7dUPbrgoF6BtGOvxGhE9XXyra3KAAWzKyYtnbjGV/YW@oG/NDjguHLETTRv6Mic9pFt7hozs7Rx88eRDaP68PO1EK0bno6l22aiteo3FlGIWeHC8d4lPwBzr0XXQERcBt01dm0D7YefAkYscDEMkBlXi429xAU8x3Sarr@fqwHEuQD6N9Sneh7aF5xonuT01XGMeFYv3dMjV/5e6Bq4dD3Rx67kina7XxyAwOx14vvXIjq7pc2Tl8sIqtvhcV8/Ddh@994d5sm9Mja0hkUYX/lZYhKqJ81Um97qRdd8pdd8pfdyqI8hWZb4U0KJZu2rysieXrsJVreVevZ1S9nlH1ekbVOKNzTvJ1pyUpLsGWIi9xuxZOmcsGXZmqXU9RuZ575XoZFXEJcGV@t3fIloUX9M3mbVZsxmG730HUmf@@gJ8Nz7lip0WwPfq@GH0EIpVyoIdJL36La/7AATyFO7WOp9Cu08MFIOz5OVkLN/SDBx8dERAeYYCHVVrO2MQzCNjXeILaOiRTqyn5MtnCD11ViCLTNPHrgGV2JmCUWIOsn4Xb8ysV5YKs1Qhf4Ul4QEJ8xDc7phoA4wG7UCgiHCtkPQCf9WhzP6HfXSHnhA4eCwaeYwo2UZo/5qQaHn8AeVo/e7L/ZO/waOfo6WFDbl2ExyNEpXAcSC06hOWW1uWh8CHeoC7YofX0WA4bkqMf28BBZz8qF8HvTC0WrbZQtFmh@C2Ms37mOJJET4iQhAvIn8Cz1KgvSs3gxGBHJaYVFB4OUmGHNdAzJ6COGGiepgmVViHysoRHuu9DsUL/q59qo774qb8KfuwPEw7PGQchve@63TBF3yRvvqIU7@3sP3h6sEeiDM6o5tTqBoNaOc@OoQ9PoOPxvAibHqWSDKMkoa5qteS9JCAmKSZJhZ7pQY@Ax9PqkjE94GkgYewNklqn8AGDybhSpP/@kXSRFHGnSRrCJqNMJSFZoHlKKHhe3xEQCbl7sP/@3gHB/O/dpc6IIgRBjvDYgb/4fpd9RCU65iv6zKE3DJVSqC3ftboVPOXDMEkip6jhUUFdgkfcsYMwiDmhHyShlEdHxOY@fJimRy9x80eTROd1zI4UwZqjHGA@JvvYCT2qI/7KSvyxKI6jRwkCvZ/SkzCvHBKZpgexsY86suNbY9CU9KIPNuCMMSjRVJCyfAsPCsF66Llj70ojwT389ExUkezgFyDxO5M6/R4QZHbsBOxMufCcqQRQqBjzqixZp5llXw/i5wImN9egkXTMvuUQ37FAbg4q5AVQMM7WVthBMoJQT16LEoGuUJOAmvJcQKbVD/FUfiKM9vBwwKYnXf7KL0n9KgFzAOavhuaJfAdsXwttPTB/nZmfSUigUvLaR2PivMxnCA@NDUvAMsL1rJ/@FD8Ky6fWFeW47Z1kknm5Cg@lmid5cmu9KQjrDbm2va4DIoOXkyY0Z2kjd2LeHfS6@32pyfMgXOckaePs7Cx5b@OJ9SxPCkLXUgsvJ9MLraC9nFxoSunl8UgpNMSXkxZfqmWPW81Gizx58uHr9us0PzmhY6opILDdx7yS4xOVMjnbKmiJ4zJ@MA5KeExewXXcI/in5lfdObOO5k4P6DbJk0SziV9w5Ys8sL1kC/6UUzyHi/GMRl2si1ut16/TDV0PJlNiWdbI73bhdgckparpQwJN7TY0IhZBIk36pkiEKz@c9Mhkx@z3x3v61BrfC7bFolgS1TnGtPnwix@EV/WDp08JeUqePn11sIKNtTKZlCA0qHkSOT4AeTc7IZW2nk/gJ9/@4tO1i@zZk/bmX3w8lMw1fD3G11cvHqL5UMnfWlu7dedOLpdVVZWZn3zxyc/v7Ozk7mbzTxr5rZwgr23@@Z@tranqpiqttXxfaSUbx8cf8qqc48W/@F6y/eTJF3y/rv3Xj17XFXwU4XFCiqSMl0YUMOKzBLdC8nnytlfiVUKBKzGlv3Yicj9bI0p9q/g/vvn4ZSJI1FXpAw/eQeJlolBKMCMYwKZFtpNEPbGJwQoXialUq9XAWPwf/w7i198DOOgz3YRHPR/BKkwTdaFGo5wn6gUwKKoK6f4/H300l0PgZ8BKatAihVLktg0MsdHgc0WV32rBtUGvTQ7PVxJkSYrCOcEgMF2ilG4rt9FigQVeDrxwUKyZwI9ePt4m4rODDPQJGfH9@pp0d1OASxxJiqI2FeU2sF/h1katJkC/QputpuVv49mXadob9t3AJebtDxauxAf/U66lYKof/NNcB2TXMkzPzXKJwtr287v1OpRcq2sb9Qy9wuZGW16xxLvuNnCdo8HYs1z8jmb1AX4Rps7LJZXPZrPbB22IQiYTRKYwmYhtBEHYV7oT7BLbhLlgww4dGVXCVUee0CKxO4sVWWfhyPNkA1pL6/nqcIk9vP7yP/zlt//ym/T3bXr/JzymyulaPWkDAp1Aw6nDtV2pGPU6X/f4syba60BtcqVUKUnti2Zqo1FvHYCA@@55Mq8lyaE9zbZVvJrpZoPGr9Nk62HyaK8nZs515lKfdws9WGDqAO8QUyQRlXOuXDHWCLkSjktEK6yExkm9JeAgbU1oKIV8S2CxGttQObxaLPPtVkJYn2LeW3U1rz4m23V2kcG6T1zMjaYWooKE@a3Pyjbzmdnq806JehStPgvzWcOFeSpDyXwplD3rUUa31yprpUqhokrt@uqrOouBFw1qmuYTP3GSiK8qCekwwmcipsw5t2fzNRFXC4kImCzEfUM4LtGoNVpmC9rIwr/TCQ2M1WF1aQWFr4Ymtc2TKtCHqglqv83LCrS27XbEzrfgWoMf/cMVW/G5Rl1CZxrk@rVGKsqGqkn5W4U9FfvgqxfxhEY9Q3mk0KpnROSVgnglEAe9CjE6nc4rowMyiq53dENXAn2sT/SpHnTGnUknMMYGfh6ZPEFBrx0W2tPcvFtyI2SIQkLLK@uJ20jhmlrGLw2DllIqaWVVKypasaAVZbWU10plrZjTikUAqBVVrVzOqapWKGqFklYoaIUyfs0ZwhQgjIYQinmtrHGJ1401csD424RkoquZeeP1VKQcDS9qcPEWBHeSABFqbBxnucQ/wVVXVIVsQDcpwwNkQ2okKv1BCXd1a@xnOZIAse@s9Xqj8XqDzNeWEOYZXmJ7u5URLi4aYK5Ww/9mPTZW6cVMUNTWRSaz@awO0tCzeiMDIJ@FIEWBUKBiu05am9QrTi1MLvTfbLX64JsZ@X0kGYFm4iVkIrPZ2Ky5u/QWaesUWpDK5kLOt7cpqW1DrPo6dAvpTGZdENYaALoRdlAQGAkyLCJAgmApEGXOzn7Gm2xuApO52LyoXzQ2Ly42N@G/SZ8X7J3MucmCuw1G8L32p6/ZtSLMzL@FfKrZkOpNqRnyqhbYRamOLqLUBEMd3hCuoamlFvaOKAeJrX@efzE7e8YumOWWCLnmEhtkI4EHPGmJDS7x/PKT/wPv5uUnP0CZlsDPrHCJM0K4hLRRJtSNvsog2D10yEN2OWDGO7KiCzrUH6Kjwx4OasqS9FwkFYGqyymlVEiL2P233V4bd9CK5DkEhWB7fRMaUcR7Ca@WCnw7o0xVktjkC0XKbn/u2pVMJv/Fc7VcTDJtHLeAPvd9/@FcLmf5hMBVVVYE5bzOTuplR6n/3LLrX/zcqotLnJcJ4ihFGF64BJBRQpJAi@QS9c0hrkfEz5AI@D25k9qHwtMdYdcdjvSAqus4lgeiQm1/r1Yu11GNMtef0MazcXcDngr899agEKTZg6DNXs0Ygoje7Gl5tYla67s6aO/A6ITOS/w9eIU/cmTg7@Al/sjRK/wdBPgjDzv4O3qJv50O/o6G@LvzEn8PX@HvaR9/zc9pmlLl1/WT7qQL/8mr9cn6GcVVRikrF@sTnuEssVVvfg7QOUpWyXbycw06KpQvtxro2wKPzwXetKLXQMqpdmrl6qimVoc1Iafmqq9qqqBWw29vuH7Wn/pZXExqGlgfppHi1S2VT1dZhaa0XDn9OTZcU2nXbBx7SXUtL@X6wIvQgOfKkig4eCZ/8o2PP07WakkhSU@fzymu91oIUxAtf/Z1RLYvuaKSNAbUynnXE3Ri@fAAh4xWhphCBx061CGXh5yDE34fGx7g1ChnFTVbzOaySimrZKF8clYpZhU5WwKtU1KzajafLWSH2VdZLavAv9VotJ81VLC9gp8Kdy77qtUA7pu/XWy1Gq9at5RyK5NTIS@Qo1z6c4AeIprsW1mIRi5RI@vKuiLbsiErHaUDBovIHpEH8kDpKlQTlU0iT@UpkYeu0gWTCT8ZTJbcI3KfyI7sQDDwBVPQlgM09eDVh18PAHnws3CNVkeRDQIJ2ait0o9UKW2MKZPzNnl34PpBdtTkGiRJ@Ofm8@fPcZhdLFgt/GZBg3/@vClttNRyiYjYMMV243kz2eKbPJ5oq5ZzpDM115rPeRCvZJ5VILqQhO83kq1qQmo2pbBigXAQCRcX7fbeo7vttoT9fJOY9cx2Bjqp7e0adFrhaytRr241K7QbjLrChLS51axrApoLGejRVHAj900gqKyU@YzXDDC862sUAa3np89Bm0udok53egKv08jwQRMebabtUW/p9IPmnJUa4MKwkvTBEggLBsi1401jyQ3@oBz/U/2tf17/h09JOtVopVNnF5speqXxl06fXZxdhM96OpUKLalN@KED2DHK2UUdjTTQGZgaqXQrfXHB3OCZSm8ygBBls06jzoKdoaBPkwTxJh0mzB6p/zlvEhcnFV7N8Oz75/zmpmecN6uU0ebkMknwz8FLn02fNJsTGVhEJzpwW3DIun5Ox5rTVQO/ZrfeaSitP/8ePVR9K00D5XPVqrJBmEXNqdVqLrIVS9VqKbKsp1Ll61dd3lIKoAbmcul0tQqWrQisDFaI2yCvM6RGmvBs3b7NEimp5@cRTC1XyMg4bVWtRinlIVnT1w3a3EE7PNt/TA8kB36RTxBkC/Q7tLRvkOknDU50O5Vcb9cqk9u3U@Fna7d20rdvq2X5/FyRS5lGCTmxnNW0YlYo51uNykSEXnrgdn06MXGr0EqStOulHuEnRgFoSlDILbVO4ZeBE6u5IngTYBYpTI6keOx50nw6valhmFwOQqWgN8gD45fpr0ifKvYKoDC10g2MjJ/gSrXbnbFlB9Ajtdvp9C1FA36vlQEH8dhbkk9W@cQZCGmlotUja@ttxvz4KvqQ/wVXggCnIWcXCUpdJJdPp4Azp0E@v0jgz0MmTgU6LZ9PV3OynDi74FlgpVxmodMkV0iVMuXwV1tLkzoIn@yHErSWyW0UN7ZxKNGfrLiQz1fPzJpyUTszK/iJnYuqEX5qEjdxm7dva2Wo5pKcIHfHeJREtsmFnUQNBBGUY@HR5JLJDLl1m8Md7l6yUt2m1KaU8iSRrDJHIQmdDSmVM4qkbuSVEiKds3p4NAMIY5xCMbNG1jiVvvHBlRm@1tAxwSWujCnc@Oe6cJEu6ZA@XqSPaj@xiE0vYhPmT5@GEQdy2RX6xlYalw4URC5mfLFpDy2vsUaVJA/GhoUDjk8e7OzuHWXVTYEk1Hs7u1n18OmdhILW/MxOvTW0H@zt3H38FCI8ebC3c7j37v77e0@fgLtPTmdX3K1FnVvcyc2ZlthPyQfcC@@Vbpq6OTbN9ul4fPqSvLCstgW1bo@hbG7fI77ZhiKN9FnxqnAblq@/eKF7I3qRy@9@@fK7v3D5e9@4/L0vX/7et3/yybe/DPf34f4Ge3/jj8p5fP7kk1/9g8vf/T1w/E9w/yncn/7kk9/8iN3U/kO4/8uc2w/Dey4cuzmA9bWffPLN7/3kk69/B@7fCe/vXL9/5dPl97e/tPrGeN/8g5vDfOPfwf2HDFYU9hu/y9zwfS3877JwX//O5a//e/b/8/CHxt@7/PUf4iO0/PJ3/vy/XH78H1W19Of/5vJL37z80seXX/rq5Zf@pXr5m/9Gkecff3D57T/@6z/5w7/@k39F/9@nzz98m//ld375r/7Pv/q//upPwvtTuP89mD79q/8ILfnv/vi7@P/mH//dn34X///77//dH3/r7772r6nht5jhH37nj9jzRx9/@Udf@rUfffzJiueXb3x@8hbun/wTuLx9Pt8GztuU67O6fPIz5ecfg41ZKkADQLm/ePmbXwHi/XXopi6//H3cVAL3iv/3VYWG@T6z/X/AoF4vM/rIYIL7W5df/gb5ELH0vwGW4E8@/BA6qA/Djv3DDz8MMfhV9AP3D6kjuxYjMs/Id@bzVTILB9Xw24Q0nj9v4ZTyAmhq@cknv/Y9akuYlTqdLsSOv6SWMhuguW2Uy/E84iaG/0oM8nOzX2IRUr6kOY5TDXPwVeRiC4l9Ffnf5Xc/uvzev7z87m9dfvdrKAIIuXJ2JysobxB7IGD@LcJhwMLbhMOAkHw7Q8dThQyYzXMJdz1tnxNShXJoJa05C25Kvd5GBX4EHpXKxllW2GqSAivxBY2L26ZAqlUE9VZma00iip7VNjQdAko5Fo5UnG05lylu6LrEtc8l3GJFzsmcUVJYSEkNccm8cCWXFEKWFDX2Wo8AxMXgEhnMboYKRRuRqJbXyCQTlmQSTt2jOwSabFDjhLAZlgn1nnATOsMf/WfGCUcyVEiiF35GKzJSQxgvWh1QhDssSB7SykziVQNUgCRMdttgLnThA008B1oUnSvNTGp1NOBcBHjdAZ2lVstgxBrLFFhZ/uolQvOTydSg8Bibxcm2SwhicodCgZg1iofahEXMILx6hJMMh040N5lS7S4kWJvcRYcMAqdgnz@v1Uu1SR3BvWZIyUwyd2ieEFgtM6m/BnuNwoR4XOLua8hKqZbJ1EuYIBaS1VG2zWoqTwtHy46z7qwi4I1L37a2CbnFKyWezWitIcJYaHxmZqExIEY5eM4rKv@cz6kyD4GbmY2wbPQfGem9QbG/RtMNk2Rlx5TXKDDSfr7xPAxIQ0JqgiCKIoEbl5lskW2yxTGsZTI0M/DKhEikxEKJI3YgFFNchtY6QxvAB2f6sVGiqrkqqChVgk6eweG3yejaJZlbn@C6tDMSysxy@MHNC06HMDlZ487O9XDd2rpOLsCpwGEImmZt4zNfmFnE2vr6Opeo8xr/mM7PZySJeMcVuvoQ2h5VtiqEL5R5dDbpUkyGxYe4lyLLUXMVi0kuP/peIicXE9x6kn7cmLCEyK0Mu7e3N8gtQCt9z7lN6CI/IaO5OTfB0LiZyfAqJFp3wbZBUZih0LhnJFHDP7gnKLlBb/xE9yw/y2Up48vCS6wl0Js8fvw4zC91eFbjMtAOVU1BO87NjsdjiG52cR1ENiuKWTGbDd8ifVMHMTSI1Dd8i@uIejKvFCrFEn7V1DEGiBfu9evXQBsc4qKyj6PE1Ehqaq5EPQklgwkuv9OHWY6d@WDb02iVr5orc2yYhSiFHCEpShE47ExwOWsKaDzNsTVxjLyiK5VUS6UkDQk1JqYgGANTUJBTsXXDdHcXyRcXrJCzeSsOn7JpBlygES/YZflLlfLpyHP3Mdl9/PDh3qOjUavWgt6GfkbXbI881zB9P4WeO4/uMvpVy4U0zoZj6Y8qKvJObq8iIyFn9u8e7B9WCMNZWHkpWpIqXd0QYqascInR6IPNhIeTHZ7J40ekXP4Qn5UZMlJqWYOoiTqXMExU0IBS8Q93lRyYfSTgh37/jjshKTnL81mlgJp1GpcfQHZ@3h0TPCSSnUwB/AFXV4pQYsx5/UyYm@5Dhzo5UDlmEBRqIFq5FBmKzKAUCxjgMfu@msbVD/eOAPLRY6KoskgO3I4Fmap/SCYiIcAFDtyh6WaFCxobedKRNXQxhI2zEv1gsI7frOWbMj@HoPUGGw1SNQ2eSq6QVfLF1tqafSYgnCYlmjNcO3oB1jMBcfIOXIR7hyPvgBNcwgXh3JHpkHDOZP9xlZEv7nkmKcj9YeDxSh44Q5rDCaIQHjeav6qIdWhqi1OtXGLti18MSL2@9@iusH8PBzAmAxKtPBWsrjgQKel0x55JffuEdK33LdyPIXYtf2TrU2jHgLCNOmAkwHnwxMXFRQ9g7t8jal2lVha3i88Lg7p0wHwx0TkCPLrHJW5HYzZc8XalUnut5IqQt0rltaaqHDhwGxKXsHprQG507dCGxH68U8spckZh0wQph6R5nq/6kClNK0kbXELheXhpmsbRNkS4iskRurbstVyrCSGbzyl0aRmHR@frk5oaX2HYya1ZWE1mYdEHPEg/8Igc@RWZX2iLegYoCi62pl9PrYZMRb59W8ORKy0nx2UnFDXkAup0XctptJLumU6AdEbQt5XIFcPJSyhnK8HZZkC6NTAnmlhwmi5bvI5fsPfJGEIWcsAUTyuqQteRV3JqLsETDI2sUivJXKKRAB7ANVrAC/6X/1oNrjX55/sHtDQaNW4CvHT@Dp0xDH2HF8c9dB/P/o8fD@etN/6Hj92Hj92hC3/oLR8ik6/O/tXqgvXmf8hbkb1Wq5DVwJwAvcEvJ@fB@g/f/ujvf/0//P1vfFXEK7TFDv/w7W8x99/5VXx@69t//61f@Ptv/QZ1@ZW//51/FXr9w@/8PrkLTGD6SkfavPz6x5ef/NHlDz69/Pi3L3/wJ2id/3/yb0Ovj781cwQzulz5f4v8za/857/97a/@9acf/e23Pv3b3/rjH330dbWk/OijX/rb3/r0r//0awTsP/7hV3700df@5pc@/tFHvwjh5v8//uFXI68vxY5gBpfrf3AHuNz/f914IYPG1SB0gcNmeJZone5VaCjlXGsPeFyDtDajY0brEHqTbaMkeE5MjUcClAKLufF137R7Iu4AqPGbo7omq/xmeFZ5nbxvOtiHhPHr3VrXNeiXxqtd0cIvvuOGQRYvl@OrroMnCtbiSX2SSp/1a6f0IICqWeuLeHaN5@g2RO@43anoB1MQEg3Xdr1aElTeJMjZ71uuTakYzDtd10EZ1qmZoGbhfMOWpuUqUD5x5I621HxRIEJDkUHwxFspZbvQD3pb0P9W1OyauVUsVrqiYZu6t5Wv5NHbiNd@bOXlSl/88OGD@0EwOgCJyfSDrVwZIuD5b3hS01apks8DS@H5TIOm2MJPKDMBQ1hbg/7Y1LsCvHFpiC@opVaFpl@rJZNbmqIKSkWTS1xY2BnCnKoj5JTCllwJ5tFI9mzLcb0sz@GXXuNawAocKPWcnNuU4E2g7nGdCohTdbJj9k3sj2jNKZvSCGkCjBBUB2MHjPlNqQNGC4zlTckC47iuKfKmNAajUc8p4GowKsHaIFa3BmliyTKY7SySS3agnIXyRcVxHfOCq2T1rHVGa67S6/UuNs4yMwtJbNO16eqVtelnoLedCSwc1PaFoGc7Z7G1KswgcBUyzgrWzBNc9B4Qz1m4YKfCq/kSX21UZ/Ziga@2Lrjtodm1dPx@d1M@ux6rACIhg5qAhJqEu6h4rhtUOmbP9cxZQE0pRAFZhq4HyPEXcXJNGVM8u55cYS7Q5GyG1xifHds1jsOU6Gctl6WVy/MXnBGiwzO7FyyhbCUbObKolGywGrFCE8@ecYmNg/e1eh3o9ixXVHP5XF7VCoV8UQXxt5wr5EtANnJBzqsqMI9cuVQuXkCrlaTXCfpdPLJ7FrXmCv0yQkqvsPNCGy2Sfv3Iss9KmsDYTypdBXEp8ZpL3Dp4X63XV4/DpUCVeF8V6jUtXwaThiZVo0KVqgqqJmiKoGj4f4NBxf/bh1fhr@ITYmkqd4SnKT0CKR4UGIc8wANhApccuS7dhXbHNFaE2B3o9OSmXc/1/X9EmDu6c8y87lrs6N7Y676O34/zh1YwWBHi6WhoOT5uZfungrA37EAGkduzAHfg4dmuuyxAkTx9Ao@D/XfvH8Xv5aV@GB@GD8hhp@FDjKO9nd37XIHcefzo7pVXPgSXJw/27h3F1iLzjaLmYxA/v/fgwVVr@Mo9fnrQG7se3ty9x09zs0fshJv3uBxci4FiZwokfKAVRTxUVcgayRcjg8LhvsHbuTK5HRrzhZlRRuMHbGei5cdbC9nm1gp3FG1X1Al2AR2T4Pe2zC4doqVnQ4YjG0qxzHEj4rinpCiTrmvbOn7QvrcGjgPdJx3TRDXdtpESMelT17O7p1bXXAPRGNIoK/jxcMwEdx@ADMfGABMALQlPFO7ip@ZxEUbHHptkPCIrHeGFTmj0rP4AJI1TNwrAdXSdwP1ZL4hvzl/BzQ4BS4O6XfOxrwfnEtzOYxyASfD8Ls/f1wNdKj4jKD4NKnyQ5/s4wW37Qbeh8jm@tbaVKwGX35Vx2N0i6lSXFKkKOFQK53V3W9lom/1avqBsYVdckzPbiVKpyvMj39d0JwsMMlvBQZRdr@ZYz4hRdSqg2Rc3CGma53YmV1NkUqkcAteAMMA6Ojq5b2KLAabMtnezQSJKbpW/@e3v//jPvnX5lU8vf/AbKBGSu65n6LjqHVVzQhXtUEMX6ciQWi7lS2VNLWVL5VIurxTyeVwsqRRLxbKcVWSlpBRK@bKSLeXKIMrlcCllvlwM9XtJ2iA7Ng7pZZkOL21UALxj4Ae2N@kgkziocwm23oe8SulpktBj@5jwJsThyY7TN22AgaODAd08u2HVoCMnUHitSACyTgySuHdvV753j@fvoAWXOe7KPN9FS74ky8U7PG9Sn90SSqu8y@KU8NRIPmAWWb4DlTpmAPBDCTw/QMteAadseN5Cy@7OvXuYTg8tKsaHYMfMh1nsyFKEYA5aNI0BeBlDg2A7LJ0czegeWjBJ9LnHfHbBj@ffjbKDPgcsGANwPyrpzg7P7zPLzg767NJi51lGP4@WHXrxvAcWaHA83wdD34OmzvMdMGKz43kDTMZUBzf8qDmese8EOs9PGXoQQTw/oaF145jn25E7JvN@mJs8YrdCLQor9Ta1lPHH82qUaQymxRaN53OxJQdlu3//fX0QdM0@u6YeextQ0vv3Nd2ajPfudd59t9Pvd7zpzt67B@i1u3sfRJzp2Ov0O2HEThsuF2Lt3lf14@H06gWl3m@3K7q91Ovz7XZOd654tadtE3MIsV5CzsKrjwkN27vgtXu/va0vWwlFAbaR4wzh3cHrzhDed/QO84ou6kXfk06Hr0IzAMWmmeJQF8PFTNg8j4GDO9mhbnhuFe2TGpHp4vtpoyC3qtSDDEGZkqsX6N9L4VPHEfj02bQxqcmt2qRWVNm4Wy/FNydq3uKza8MtpZyvrOlbiprLTCq4vM7tJUlSULZISrm98YqkHqW3VFCp1vjm1pbAN5TWVqH4bGMMFY@PLVUpVXKyStLMqhUrEEdOyoTgI90otraK@coscrGY0SW1UiyCMAj4CUCk6OCQd5ukUqemfpxOY9bpkCmUhxacTGmhrWovNclOaiyTZJquTmpKlR1MTeQr0FKpLn7tYGzgqTiEAe0DwAnoVLhAMcUr5RIPeZAkXMqJA3kMOWc5uXRxduafnTUvYlYpgWk2aP3BF46Oj44@BG4FMsqUjfXVw@HeJ56JPC9aMf/u/V1x/3Fkww8ZiPdQXHY9cRd53IIPk5sjpyNQq8T70NGDSh25QZzAc21xj66wB5k78ohOExLDw4bFo/sLcA4H7ilLGSL5VRTrdDxxAb/zYHWJXquDCfqQFM0V0dOnVMRo1@u1dm1oDkfBFIoYxfo8oR9BmIHZ91ne6Xdn@qZHaPSznucOQ492Tb6odmqTxEQQyA5IfGMvCxDbNSIoz4du97maMapd/NDDndodBFNtw7tTNWum57keDzotX@1tObWx4@s984np4TES@4/XQfTBU1hSPWKm10lzD0PvoqZ1IdQ94szy@Gg8TOlCvZNedMIpktgB0ZT6QlT8M5wigJzz/EW1VyOpZxD0Jdi9dZLqinfSW7kqYOwOaafBSX7ee94jKinkqlQxSiEsaIIUU4gBPV2rfx4kNgb6GDpzyE1Y5ccAFRMDwFAb1EdPj6yLqlGzSUogkzTFUa7arzUw@jk@NgWebwlC47yFMxwfoLbwcgydZx2ae3Wa0Gv@uEM//UPkjqLKheoE3JRirjqA@tafTapebTT2zKoN1nBOhNAS61XALaAQwLw6T11@5aP0ppCvMbcqBXWOA9ltsV2bVB08tBUopabVwCPTyMnZPK6qzRezIEKohaxSyGrZXFYooivID3SPBSpmrbW1lJ3iCeGz8kQWlaxiKtmU/NzqPk9nj1Mo7lDkpbOBu@eMhwRdoMqQWqkd3no6o24Airou0TcFSrzAZKpYLsD9gIys7IBCOjB1m0VIC0TbSNnrKQy0fjQe7TValcreZPQF8EoJL7cKmaKceZVOV1Nr6ZpvvqTzR3csIBAdkIuciRZ/tAY0Hc4bEX88bECtg0kpqpVGo4NlLcpZTdagmFb7vL/J1/lWVl4rKFBnF3R6QCGMs8zPlIDkxM3cRm3UHGwT6lApq1WObi1JkDvemE7daCVVKEv5jbzMpksYCG4UskjELUk1o905yVQyWVSTyZmanU5WcWp6jZ/NFFLl@4xyyCSwbJK8reYLWzwIgHyFL6s8BJtxXMwlkaOcb4Bcavq6h1NKHA5ekBwo72fcxdnFZp2biNze0LItPUscy8Bv6FnGscjdc71ulnSsPunpAbZlkduB0u5XRO4QND@Tmhp7@B0FwuLTA1QwWisEWKHzbcFgClKwB/GndPoxEK@7Qi0RfEdJLYYgn@MO8fyNTfUZ/orPHu48xt@97QRuWSHbnwO/MriXnj18@vjp43v0jIXZ1ufPcm1zRKL7UiZiu5qo0lkAXKsByWDRKp9h8fc2zsgTaQ0PDyAZURDr9ICKbZZKMzwqSVoj5LNunMls1p@xdxM3jwJojh7i3iAtunTctFBxJ@/rIFBukSRUue4NG6qqtRpqEcQS6LoaMguqqkoVctFO0J3QdaDvyRlkejNTx2MoPk@mUz0jREW/Ter9zLqsThMnbb5Q1uhJCe26Ih@TteTtDfw6uUASJ8drdXUjk3xS0TLJu0ktlzhJNdfrGWWalMhGRp32cNUaro@SkhBONTduaRvJp5lKqZ@tKBl8qvCsJImwlthuZ7fTZZ@jlEwSCwheK@/UdvoHO9FS/p3dekmdhsdnJJ61@VIxzGJzHVCmZp5tL8Svgyz0DOdyr9Tbz7LSfxtXxierycRZkiSSF8mLRrIFoBuN@DSWWmuWfVzkF66E0HIFkk6QdGgrlhN@Kl6G8LnkdiKJc/3E918DQdN6oM06Oijh889VYDIJx40c3HGA474gRuXzOJOdkJ6P/C@qJe3h/mPnrnfP5BLNtfM1F1cpkCrPQPLktfPeF0CthdpKkmYtManlwqlgpV4XlE0VD0crkgoIAD2lIMjndcbJ6tSjoILP5Ve@k5tslsCuygrYVTWfUet1ZQNE0MTo8pMfBN6UnO29v/OAJHFi@cd/9j21@OM/@326mD55QSebVa2YgJBoVArFxNnZ6OwMBMAL5pdPtBLXFga2AE2SopeLG2K1QqRSqbwhtqVEuI8xpRSVdMIXEuEui0JeSKUUSU1vaCU5DT7n4QFUKVUugTVa9EGd@EKeTyf2Dqy8qmxvbkHJtrScWl1rNHglHh8n8W/T9MsJLlF6@PycELAY9W6/b6nUJElhG3otkM3Xwia8oYZfC2vkea2OqxsVPPYlWj@wgUdG4IKeZD0jbSQJ6Nmk3rioXrQydBECHQd5tuE0ryCjuYZ7jBedNhz4mRs@/ZkmtVIHH6yRzdx44fOpjbQkdbu0z8EFIIJQTzCSbZskXwd62ZAglxvRmgH2E4Rm@vIrv6mqhR//2a@ct8/bH6qqWi6XC4qa@OlPN8fO2De79Z9CxCfRUX9ARIbVRWI9co9Nxxfj8Qba0VkOfkPNcuJxCsJOG7TCWLFBNHguMXZQF2Pho1ELHJ8gII9afcfs0tEK7gSlaVqtbXa4XjdFg20QUEayVJejp3mlqxwX6TlMV/P6RpbCIBt45HWjlebOuHfQC3fRgr5X5d6ZgQKHIUhjrtH27bE3onuzUzSe0sqS2xAFUngHDy5cg9BpEvbZAnBh6KevRWVZ9inWqLxN8HR2PAYRRBHuHYgSHtFvT8lI93yThrQckBNEDELzST26uHOqBWnbLEKbuqZo6VmALGG5Y5EcUOG4d0C2pFiwQOQk1iYEqAJPeQcQAGVIhYCtFtkkWpqcWZlMdXbG4gWeqOO4gMLoEEAOoyG0LqApjlzFcOAEqiN@hxjpIqxh4HtzjhEQBoOt6KuB8onRqQ2FeQvIYfLWoADW6QBriBaN3L49y1WtZnXThJYI4R9bIxy9pfXgLM8rAIu0@FvAUkGcymSwst9ZJDvAeIZmF6hOYMdWVueiEh6tFxwH/7cmWqTIK1VFPapYgLC@WKswAGUQGdHO6tAgmzWiqMU0iTNvQN4Nmil6RFQ8NNGc3BLVDyPPC8jhTxPRJ8WAWR3Nj4iHdHvXtM@H5zHCfQIK2JgesxsMdMYMuqZtDXGpII5fI9PbD6LYcSwoimXT0D3LAzWYLhyMzk5MaUoao83OmqT5oFsb1RzBfYf5NL5oLAxN4K3jWX5hOmtUdDVcqFB/5Dr08L8AWRPu8QSKAB4FCTxyA5Nle@yc4nf@wrqhkedzBKUELQcpH3NMDzN0HdNncXH9Xccz9eMIN1li9kViDLtELZMUJTQHF5o4Mbg0jUQz3AHtCXHcsc0hZOnQNOkRCX5Fkvog9I07OEsuPbSArgb3LOh@HF@6yxAsnVrHlnSEZ7oLbg9PUqDAAQrIidj82Ao@UDTHdpfYrntMbOvYZBMdqfmDFPHTKYUsKD5ZwOzsBsRWUORVtSwOgilZFgruIryKzFjKzsVdS03T19@aspZqY42e0x7MglqxzRPdmcMvvc65cCDFn/ocPTeyRlBxSIFdjFkutEx2BFsST0VMpkXAfRckLFq/PkTBmCJOoI1SfIJPi/7ItgJq5EaeeUJwIITDPgaYptEOs4CtGEr7Du0AaNuDloVnOQZeBWouAznxuikDml7I4B1yi2gqhwEhZQzKMgAwsOpri9DBD6JiOfygCxUj0lkj5CvQOodd8MOz4kLyw/gRdaOZnqw5I2@yFoLDToemVSOsWUSW/JwFWwfSMy36GngWIIdLcrKW4jMANsOneQY6jn81OqN2jvKSCrkOKUsQQohqgEJFBR1ZDp50PfehPlxWckcH7ozfYkCqB6I/PT0V6bGlY88STR8/Xue7jm5Lo74F4rArBeZwFH7e2zKkUQR3ZhLYtynF0WC0NUGhtla@PWVvjuv5tXBBbirZ85PYOZ7gt9n6wxPUrSDDPZ8S1D2Lfr/RSIULhBn9qa3sWUR/lSQ9AzB5gUAIQTCT7DRrZAFYtmMcZ3v/b3tfv582kiz6d/QUHZwMyBZfju1ksPEsNjhh1zE5gJPJxQwrg8DMAGIQtmEyPr/zEPc97quc17hPcW99dEstIWwnmY@z@5uzZ2IhdVdXV1d3V1VXVd/29uWHG5qQABxG0VEvMZnwTP0Ye@ppOO37Jdw5rqP@p8vRT@RhAJASfFoQNM09VCWX6qf8PR2iJ//EuRWl2cxepui7iaWRgVNLEnvEErZ9@gKPsM2IT5zZdrhoLduh6gu/Omxqvo8RLOQp3LnuBcppjvH7gr8v4PuCvy@CRlWzrUWbRTJ8dYfdQa7HkARVEsEsVZk7TgkcfCHIIIeLPIPAksvQO3Rc7haptqI3/4JxLCrGAJ6YAsGdVLb1w0Xroj3xnNvN9lZ2AMyeIELAiAPoVptoetvzn5H6o5vR1PVCr2D7IPFG4o2vuleSG5hXsI/@ABFjML2GmMZ1MJa@TywQyA4DBJTD4COKBqV5amju@3m16SMwTisR0JgRa0lk2iR9yU/yHYhLTHomrA6orQHC936XAE34ItTM4atK1erwYeZCGVU2TbcrwhK5FMl2EigZmSq81uzTIGlYpdMKTSA7iqvFaFfUdxiKVuST1s07Of46@k8/G/0@zIt47IlhecPYN/SpguEHIELI6UJUFYdFbVwBg@ymPXJmsHNVWD6VuzU0s5lVaga3g13wbofz7lVKG/yuyeNDOS4Sk0TBZ4VlsQhdXBZ5WvK8UCRlgvvVPFltqRhB1ucFBGDkYqs5stpCr7YoFnnhEIs11W41JBeE5IKrcOnFGiTbshpoT1W1veDwtEE6xbiIBMDL8zYKYtA0ITz7xkGfjh@vx1PUqlSbwZpDXCB5CEVs5LNuO7b1loa0tmhFACAjrgDo8S3mBSO64OXT/i9/jWJSqjWKf0k24LUCGIyW4H2DdSCfyUgHBoE/sUX7AMzdxFbLSOTpmAD/l@P/EpZ6qf7Lr77MhUvmwy9zVuR/v8vLNlJWm6Ca9JHP7eCCbASWCt1k8dYFbTCwQ2gOE9orPCgKv4MFYELFWIMbI5QUKW73mhfIvsBTnNkDP5IUFaycsERJfYwXGitx7lE6cGpEUCq4W9AzLiYJc1@7kUBZGYKNUYiT6mlFbFIITJ8EZyU0J2YJllIYjafDyX0I0MkeSd44ichq8dwrwH@Ag6VAApnIfpEi2pgP4kYUubzutyhdlpwIxKcCU5UF2CCCfVCOJ3i0biWeeyJhfQMVTWTcSu3ENMKp/eURSag@IOdNJymoZSXSmQRVhXeYagYhhUHwaOJ7hTCgjLKpUsRQocAL@jJ0MZGzgK5MBg4pZnY2/yq3961BvZtYc2vc@rZtbXaLCQFLkD0Ze9ez295PA/fqpi9GYvrj5aK7/OVnIXZ3BOb93P6GQzPze8UsBZJRyK74NkeXMkgEv6PgU0yqnlHm7KSg6xg4luGpoKshBPkpFFAmjHCp2BwrLkSjwrw4bu21ixNYhMetSXsfzRrzreJ8K7@Vwhff5E3Mp4Q1U93WvA10udNm0abx2gatBu8MFaVLjw4@YU8zQuaCOeyQHp7A0sEFXiQ1GoKgT8x0SwqpjBsEZQUYNoCoX@RtVPuo2VN5C5@keg@VMqKGkG@HKJT4Hzy8dtCjHRaPV@d4xwCAxKMukDAoxT/ssi@2WWl3BPYIS8GuPdCRwBFHcwxOf//igIwhL1EwuKvUFzSO4Z3PAhVXPPGHnbpgGP9xPez@dPxabOdyL/O5F3mNZHjRLyKYy7zYCbYrIJL6sI0uPrv5HcM4dqdLduKDzRxh7aQRoCVOUTl@D3qZc@NMJo5RGo3Y28/Duy6c2Y3TyxhG3emRI@nlNVEE1bhrJBdote71rMsXJFwOJ/ZsiXyBt7fQlQow@fEveimOQdXpy5sNLQOtIKCQjYdztpW4N0O8iMS3/PTd0ci9RYJ10ejC9MBKYwf2OGPTFGGUkFgKF9L3x9feHKc0Wo0RoH2J9/B2fTJMYPPrwsiQCcMYASgy3GmNTXoRTKC97shGVSsThwA0pFFAIQBd6113nXtxMAiJz8RByI6p4A1bjUzWnRkuzZWxjaotyHUBgWlUqJqGOwxw8021IRq1k@aHUr0i4Pldvfa@Wq6UxdFH0XxTEce1dx/JRVe8qZ2WK/WGwBjX49pZs149Om/W4EWi1ICaCfpglM4@isr37@qVRkPU6qL69t1pFaAB@HrprFmtNCxRPTs@PS9Xz15bAiCIs1pTnFbfVptQrFmzqFVVzQjqidqJeFupH7@Bn6Wj6mm1@ZFaPKk2z7CxE2itJN6V6s3q8flpqS7endff1RoVgR0zytXG8Wmp@rZSzkD70KaovK@cNUXjTen0NNLR2oezSh2RD/XyqAJYlo5ge8SWqJ/lar1y3MQOBU/HQDxA8NQSjXeV4yo@VL6vQHdK9Y@WBNqo/Mc5FIKPolx6W3oNnTNSD1AFxuX4vF7BkyikROP8qNGsNs@bFfG6VisTrRuV@vvqcaWxL4zTWoMIdt6oWNBGs0RNAwygFnyH56PzRpXoVj1rVur183fNau3MhEH@UMF7Yo5LULVMBK6dcW@BSLX6R4SKdKABsMSHNxV4X0eaErVKSIUGUO24qReDBoGITb2b4qzy@rT6unJ2XMHPNQTzodqomDBg1QYWAJjY7ocSNHpOvcZxArz4EZjVUJxr0XCK6okold9XEXNZGjigUZXcQmQ7fiNpnkHnWk1AG@Jdko491oW2/uqrGwcdwlalvXj5zz9/Oq6VKyKhzg0TwYdz2HVeRQ6m9G@w0/gf4WfoAKDnXF4POnhJD0rsfjUWqsbewMIcD5hSUVwY95xTS9mNKmxsdDrvS51S/XWj0zGtx9QMofFQDUq3inll15cyZR8x@gxtaChUFgpM94MQoQ6/QXGw78wswU7IVJKp/w1trhN7DLpiNttzZDU0hSBgJZbCHjxzxwKA9XBpJCssRsMHTZLUQ7@Hkh2oYkqBz3Q78Bp7zoVcD/6Z/Br84M1BewGrM4vS2ezAmTMaoKCqZrgRMjDRP9K@A9oXSfKe4/w0SOX05pxJz8zgjVboHSnrUNm5MxoNUuYD1S@dQaR6OlqfkEWjpkqx7HGoAWsXyJh8DiZJJuS4ZGbUsxT@05nTH1NhwxY0NJRQU2SClwpR6huu3sq1kaxsKASJmgcZZb63pe@rH1DJzW3v7Efev/Hf89xCh0H0LYUNr0X12vTnTZsLwAQjyyaQZCjtjdmsVgfEMhIo/cK3UPAKC/GNXLhXXzm0rwNJQJC9tkd6m7gbz4YLHXtYh1/XS2@Pzk9OYOlEbHde7b7c2zf8Q8zvLf77Edsh7046w53CPg5yGn3SZskxCD40UzRX/ID9iYGzWSyIoR1q0OglWs38a69YSOCsGCRLHWB3PUwNMUEzSMKZ0FVdZM58aih@jZ2ZkgFSoa6a2JuxvSAR3wZZiXhAHpqOljRqC/wHYfvTX01xv0OSgSSLkb8rcK7xhNe9BFaik7a@ez3hYxAskkkoPuZDcZ8GeI@XyBfkMSL9krytjSIItjjQOF9p2KkmIPE0ioWQeih5dkMT78hqK5VLOouFN99LfoPHj9JdgJwHbG9emjeAjCd@TdSBA0VXdrolIbcx1A6PqFVLBwItCKZEiuaeVFV9M6s2GwgVjIJF61QY8L5vlY02iYpw8m9J0LeZU9EUinD2JcfK38C5cd2RUPaVNVb@VjY@wbB8kzFT7dZvw1BFPvpWQUXOEJm@ih4E/0@kSQz8A9A4AXpALc2l4lGUJKhMK1BfiSjDW2XE0CwnATX1Vx8DMHf6wFz5HZOWoQW5EiAJ5Ogs1YuP5ETST8UQAJncRM8Cbf72XIduUoedGVSnvyVMWR1tMJPueJoScq9QW8UK3PRe2yKxy1J2G/xhCpMMs0Jr8BSqir@x4nZJsx5UpogqL557CQZnKmtqdhPPM4IJT1yKFMmryR5wVk7OMrUOyIMrbcPp@edPIJberbUIbgrN4Si09kurmiIUgD5EfFb7STGHruiOXM@J@K/wrRFN8ilAz31LXrYoHQDQ0wBdnBDO856Q9xg681vcIEYMnRwfAmgi9Zx8L7ARPpYIBAe13JoZIC1tq7c@9gvC/lbD/nzC8SX0syBUiQz7mEgMJ3gRJfAMXTou3tpLQHn0uG4zi2U3G64lbh2K4mGzhKyPIZhd152B6GhjvwFHa7g0M@KDNDo4E@96Jr1BYD8bzqRFQgn90AyKTay90zbDcRuEmjcEuWGONhfkD@rS2LEn0kFkuEjviRQwr@LRQ2RhcmtZbOVF6iD4cgA0IScvIuKB2MOUa1SKCSodsByi4NDzlQuYJS63cyBywfS7dWc/4d6PItCk5/R8Py8NJLxQg1SdkMdMd85dn7oeWTRgKNAC4lMiz4a0S7v70y1K3rBHv5TsBAI6vkoEvkboCUY9@fx2fCaVULGhgHFl68B8e2kYTKTStnS08l2v8tu7hEqcwnW3Vhkj36uwSVwkLib@klKQt8U@V6IjPvG66T99xCe@LdApPvdw9sAbtJ9LERQRRpkVbbar6xzhh@cVH4bOrKfbREGS6dlTNL@R6uNOiBeV6VA6UXTtuecsQQPoZoeLLMHopP7uXk06x@7IHgzdoQ16GoZWLHjFw8clPeKADWburUfRxZxGSSvUWwbPZA2Xh9r4W3rs4M/goNObO9OUfgQyny1LGESLWgwd4@NZq79fEX9PoyfOfp2d3aCSX4fwyEyvvSvQTffX1n2Rj6vMpwUIQC5wh5HTGTomd9Dnsahacqcp7bhDFbi8r4CG46VIC1v7fLcW42@BRHTAG8JYIbNy5KF3AjWztRi3egurRx4dM3cO61bZwZhVL0WvLRuTfMIq8h2eQhRE/lVOq0oZNHsL9OrAh@V6cm@//JOxBwS@Av38izhuiWMEWuL6cjbAmkzKhPTZAlzInXlIazStxLCKDQewC41CQDuLKNTw5@U6atCpIghF0mlhhStxRqZA8cEkGKkOLDmdJd2pnhRJkxwFUAQp0SU66xjW0ZlV96/R28Ejbg6xy@DCdCwhpzSk15GqC1TC9IAhmNNrHWX2UH14xmxvP3bUIgQsSgKGcNAyZ6YSSnJBT2y@v3pOx1ruDBbjRIR68lQy6c3dafKR1Fu7dsSec8fRumuuI9KnCLMVYbPc7BFpi0t8XO4bUXwiTBOmGJ1iAw@h@krPPptHibgodnC@FTvLB@iwjmbBmay/qfjj3eO5j5viDYaVqo3Gn1KEO7p87fvvWx3oeGf9CiJhsnrVoRWjg0tGZ8mPGqgImXwqPZ5CxH0S9wg9ekA5bLcHtNPHZy1RowfwyoFMfQq5DCE90Q3eHju4Lk37GehIylTnU/4i5QucC2tJR3n59CW6bOIHBohSsZMO7FBswQ0GK8JHFGvRT3XQLTCPKxE8HbLPrvJ8koj6BKMYB2ncYffeVmeZzrf3GdLChwRaBV/sfg8k@QqLtToLgrJCCpjiMaTwe7SyNl09vldf2xcoBxC4Nn32rvEIHqQp7IwptgAb@Ef/1FmgDBw0JWuGZlR4InRoaYC5AFrKYOSwuorS33DGHI@3/MhpBAoEv6ZLfLZkDXSO3sv51MYqi94Si5iS3DzbTMycRlUChuLfSH45FVnUJcUVADjyljqYH3mAgE5ihD0eCoyc/jzEeSFE5RhBxWIepyW8JB@zwIck5jsSVRbY2dVK5OJKfKvDSMcCAcEivkyACMgs8UUCKLDRxeKilXgZ35@gBAjEiveZ4jAUclTCNPRHjglIWfVyZrCitPLCykkOpo87u2boo8/f9PXbnPY1F/0K9PExbKXz0a@vcqGvoWa3t8NVQzWBHqbeaugjkMLUEfZXha/7P4NcAjUHciXhHmhKRkjKkL5fmPUQtEzQ2zI/euIATRyHSsZQ8OgwLp0nVVGpXx0OWAu5uN/vzi6SdGSAnvBf3VsVs6EwkZEXyYsJOdqzcZcVQpJYE7jVY7dQ0yVvCjSckMcJ6LdKp3X74n3z5ERXgsXlUjkajZ3Zbi6XQya@1EMJlN8WmpKGbjZcOtu/Ho2y09u/z95fZmntx/zZI88tKA3agSGBSeFl3NmA42wQByiKpdNA4LF746Cuf93v6wEteEKJgwfDxiXZV6wnaAMa@k4v75scXH8SbLD/xA5i//4p/Nl3a7OgKaGoYyioDdS7uEmo0zMgD77oo@@Xf1JFwHBhVt5MsG@ZxcNPuINgnBgNFjmDmmgWkuyfeOOMRq4lPmB@sqcJsqhEKpyc6BVyXARPGJEo6GI0Ag6zhHMzHAXnUx4W0XkdwamNSUXtKC97jDSoO4PKYppKtH5IwLYCXd7Cbm6ht68lEoOEKV3vHwGW@RDQflTpsT1NdYlO0cKw1csZHDwBRi/yVqzuEypikk1M0uzh0kjUeHQzP7rDSQq6bpIsoCIDaHipJ2uK@8RNXCzyfaRhjmFInOi@wEfVuNv/uqXx65bFm3m//7hVkYIqeGA/a0XkuLKvWxDpDIBmoJx@QE@MrvxHGqb1SSQQigUcDH1aXXewQgcrGMbzbvHn21SpVBLPpltbolQ6ggdM8nNUEmV8cXQkyphBBX9/U9ze3d3nNbdsfoKXR@rlnTgCGHx7cfdqVoaf8K2IAW6w3ZMW@SxbfGbtP@sUDw73vWyrdNTOZgfwxLdNZUvyB15DlT2iH60f/EKZTCb7rPvp2Td3@/i7VW4nn122nk3bycE@chmQoXQ9d6vztB24j2Zml8YG7wLaW/IjVXq2h3ldZVWh0iOM7dlPsLoUxEbXy27Itx7H4dIau9F1tPfOBJOggAqvQjiiqryBIfJje4nmeBidroMOeLDfUFJX8gPl@ny2ogz3E1cr4J@qbBACUma9cQA0nnAsoZPcMMYP4A3MzgQt4Dck83L3DMOGv8N5R/Jv9gd5C8TmRUps5sSmJTYTCfqDN0JsXpjPskO8aYSL@XdFBEcL6GYovCEJeqQ/UORihNyG8YwCIBGSCoemwpPr8SUan5X2h@GTMnzdGxhP6CJSNpHQIRNW2fj0bHIHw/IJStwljCcUzpjHvB8sKHSkFkONaScq/viiCGR77AgQtDxmghRcaBJP@qAyn/ll1Rs51gbFZhJgJGv99QnNe3wBe9EziunMR3QpDBql4Ed@i3vjPgfvEtr4hdsPEKADFVYncxQ2ktxI4lkHXTbg95K6KSjGU@@fZD72dVg6c6wYNP@fQmMC@vREJ9yzCb2jc0z6yPRPDP3jFa2pBJelaHs@mTG0KuPr0Xw4HckzLyIRjpzf2h3PJBxRAsRwOIK6sDrDyFCAmQ9uHQpD1oeFQ4@Xoudi13kmyOSrOB3MDJ8caUTI/pCCuf1rZG6b2SFiotiBeYCQ8l35@vZw5CHJ5yqL68CeXWKuBcrYLIZzPjcjex7m1Ilg7PZ9pDMEmVzOg/kMXdmYzuzB2LbExpnbnNnLKmxbIPnMuxkTejhJzgkJnHyy6bjuKYS5R3JIiCJ@V8hzCKO3R0sZbM5ji6NBg0FDqqaCTNCAkyDETkRJ59fQWEXoGHD1ZwyCjvLK4u2fRsolllZe9DSSkIIuwD80zVamjqFa0OeOP3ESBqPqz0zFC7LSNW60Yzr4hZUcU3yrtqmmI88HBSyX2D7uTgNnYoc2p@nIMDgxybPsvuB9EeczJfZgbyR5g1H@ZT7IH4BYgRz5Q/gKYd6b3D7LbMaTVOrJhSeD4zf0fQSF54zvi5@1kVXlWTmFg48pId/5ZMiLZWSHGjLtgQkzokqe/wChP7IHgN/y1l4iK15spL57mjVbP1xM2pupi8mvF7@YhIlcktUumxYb8jBbrVhyrsDOmLVCP5VXmgckwNyJ4mISLnAxIbcuPr2XJABEsqnWD9n2r1lA6GLDNDezFxtMkNCQISbZ@9vLIvjsCpobYSyyG8YTc9NUg5/6Lm8K2FvpL44hvzD5L2ChlEoy04OeM@sDKIoBotsKULHLvtrO7Wznd0ATGjiL9My5xv027V1fOgsQJTxUZ2HrufglxA0hQtwtPHsfXi6gn8PBBBND04h6MqGFXELlNKd2DJ@toE6GeQLKA5VTSAIMcTH9MjYePqLCbwlgOVWWMlqw66DGfSncPz13jO3YHq5r0egQ5kj0MmAfETKhphGyZLy1HGqq6ZKkYLOMOL5yYJARCAxvdkPbLSbuJC2FNTOT3EchGqNmRpjXNzpHV6ZoaIY@k8JU8qnIH3738r//d@3njfnG4Xb2wwz@zjd@3th7tcGP8AC/XqhfNxuHGwdYbO9uY5kFHRgeX/73/4H6h38HOPhleQD/HO4qWHvLjcN0kar8unG4Bw/57W1o9//@139BH56xxoaZbZ51LEGI7SuKHNsT4l34LqrYS1ZLk8GykseFBWGwhyHo5vADHaMW269yZKbbkF4VN@j@M@zPfX8UucWTY9acXIXYkqH8KUAy4gpFbCDNIJULRV9ovhvKbQOZN0BT/PN5Zs8DDeCf0p3Db9J33XjuocvQM1aLYABT3CLo8/xwmPsu4bt3FBLKp2RfiZCo2sm19tWLfWCHd64zH3bDXhJquo679q1zmUE@zDi9a9CpJt7I/XGWvQGWHOe3X2X7aNzPkh93dkqQ0tNl5hcQBGU2ElAMyenUEjMYAXcMf@EZc5SAQH/in0mp7BwgZU@dLtuwwhmeoEijWa7U6xYfD2N3MoEonaJ/QYDHPCQyrYYWeX4xgZq1ekEktvyCXI50XhOxeUfOsTLpSJq9YSl7LQgw1Ae0Dqr@ZEqzAQUhUa0ZQOAiGbvX69jyW8p4klCB55bx5MoZTYsJ8g2D3uA9ayChS/qzmLkWSnqIFoR0mhY6hDV25jao6MUEvUF9PGhhjvcV8Fkr6ca0uvhk7cuyUqvvFU/wTOuepm@56VsYUZQSgnZ8ngly4UyEXozXliKaKmdOB4/UYhuG1jyVAmuWoT@IgcfDUu1jWILsDkVAAtWC7kivMn3YLNKFgUduHY7ZY9Mi5wEzNoLgR0uVAM6qnmVQdsJ2M9wYLBBn7sQpoIcy34eHERBFlbRlOCEBaOWzih2WYKgPtanDaCpCYUcsuS1NYD8kgQNjKQWQYOh4vKkFPtgG7x4@aAlHS@iTQMNLwkSW6hdI2aKCajgKlFSLG0fNjO1Ura7wk/X0ZS4guukNXyRy@e0XO7t7L199izHjT2Rv48FgpQxqAdMrG2CQRJ0CJRvfF4uJZIJfYUKv1SYRehxYPIBDt65bk7Dix6d4xQADyyUI1i0lpuLq0lxJIAOIMyeDOwLoKKlZIpX6rtDCjrUveuav8F/CUrWZ4dDUbI@Gv9hMem0c3nFABKU5Gjtjd4bH47gw25TZBXPqwxbCX/SyjtuvO3iLFfq6MttDQ6eui0EJM/d6cKVzR4at/aIJEwYIPp8tC6RBvXY4UpR0ag0rlEWlwaGqRV8UFbzWag/QKRe3BJT5GDhMM5gM6OVvS09TnB1J2IQwzwNGrOIRouY6qrMzcefEFZWzchQxmQlt6PlwM7pnKwh3sB8C@ErtBDMfad1tAnVhSgxkr9WaZLFBn3RfucDlsBxwBTI9xkp3Ma2XRhW1VpPcME/dR5Y88eLQT2gXVIVxRLxiYOZzD5NSxbWqXiBB1EIorUn@Imb55zk6yQKc9EHGeYq8nChoPqJvh55HubxlYwlTepRSIRhIj08l4gCi3SaX4I7kCjii9FihNFY82nz9K7lM4o2pPMC@purElhz2pamAosY5s4hPC@x/9ezYEuUK/HPyoWyhoHxU@gf220@YtR7fvMQ3XxDVEzUERFBphiOfW/SZ@hlDlIBZchanLwkQxMWXDBtYjyRvpGCleiJpz5O6FZrb7YArkF1tKYQr66icJJg1hWwgT6TyTqYzmWtRKvQFNl6trjRbsrCaFmziun9iazR5ErTqQ2JSPgLEdhREWoEIuP1JwPDsgU6Sty11F8XY1ZN4ng6xLCtUILafZIHsYZ5dS5n72GJbssV2AcfxPr4gvr2XN/gmszBzPMAbT7@MN9KPZ470vwVzVP4c7nghueNFAdce5o5Jd@bQikQRnZTUzo3hmMsl7cGd3nAwRPtQX/uJnchZGgBa8OiCMpviQfI57Nua5USk4j9sRfcjdBLa3t0zvrDzO7LzOwVcc@mx7PxP7Xz6N@78ruz8bgH3mpiRl6KdDH/97XociISp8IvY4UVxl4uZX9rTPdnTvQLupjHD/If3NP079fSl7OnLAmZM4AMHTuF6PzezJFJqHFergbtFRmUgTmFWwHiuNFH3wkuyLdEfXXtXRZTWxRfj/0ri/wpXI3qqI1ltLUbZ1@VZPeVgeZYs@Ro9DLLinnB/ZaiX3l@5YQX6iNygeJEmw9ZMKiogkFv8MThtygTyY7D6@pvPY3HmtZ1yK3FmWE2BZo0wbwZTnCVfKqwSsD5hRp6jJe24WT/d@l9MhrH9k4xCA@RxaG/xjiG5k@gqGI4Vv5ad0bqDsBtS5wixiiQnITuX0d4@uzxZv6pRYovIvhivJPBRG6dLxgxUjuYBRCYjoE1G1ldaFbrmKvWC30DfuVB8l2WPv4hLv5Vc@m1B1KVisI5UtjT4SV4M9LTt3d379gCulcE/OAFzFpS/Z1b9v@BwYdX9o9RH6nTeOp63oSWLMvQ83VxGYBkRLlO6hjKzAl4XM7lE/4P3fvKpbUPLtgzKimcYx2/LDbRd2JfdntMfXA1//Gk8cac/z7z59c3tYvlLPmEYKjl/yuSshcr7RpopVvM1J2aJSNLmtJa1OQCBhvkkW03ChpBkPp80W4XCdtsUOD/HnI@JzwcCACSiTrwR3pFEbhZ@9nAaSvZgiMb2enT0780x5hxIlhrZ48ueLRYFgf7X6bwl0BtMvu0CIYFEZIdJdWH1nJqmSXfCyCsnkjrkQtLSf@pdnQ3GVbbPiURCogQ/q3QggMYWv6hvoWmRyaUtNoH5@MuwF7aUsE3GrylT66FaIPl0e6dtFoBMH@gLMvyVPZrziWDqF9P3hHHmfiQBbp3HvMjhLpIzQ4ELGtIHtAH6HTMlcwSnXNxfbV0Nfdfa8WG0AvDtUOEQrbQfWzD1/dAdAAZTwT1y3dEpjq9qwZLUsMSroDNBJkQMa35jj/r@KKhsxUN2qgzxTriPlEMWqR0amAghJDH6/koXBFNfYbOutBT79fGwATC@JHeFFVA6vlhppcAKl9AaGsrpQ5tGtB4PrzfndOIxnQiYs@UjQTmiA37T3m@I72t1GP0bezZEwxZb2/LQRsbJwPwckMP/XE6m2ERFcnJt78K88iHTDDNXkIvv0zqUU6svQe@VL7EBWnewA3iVruoC7mYDym74MNKPQPme6RziUAaL7H0C25HP3oqp83tSqEsmEWkpP8ZNuzB3I2vP0Mc49Soy2IoOOL32kFzqRZvlleDzKxxnzDkGe8DMZneyDXE@H8Iivgx8mkm4IYcxXcqiJEQMjHPzRydw98oSl/KHzK8jMdUWD6QN5em/MoNE42s6p4C12B1jS7zEM3diCB8iCHA4A/Jm3IqIjfk/s2LbXN9dKIX99FYFy0iXQ4Ma3133Wkcg92A/g/LqaRPvLg4m@gohhu0wC6xCUEutdB3GvUF@WuVsPJLqdDD3T6dDqVY6HZQfOp0kt8LChCYEafdelC5717P0zL4a2/bk79mu56XxGu7p3DC6QNaDA5GsnJWTGGrlf8pMlzAO6c20kHn6BYkc@MZIJMJRpseNhmgc16vvmoK@GTQmXXc0cqR4IGWk2qyH94OWh925EptYylO/xjamFTLoQkpx7HkNwoV7iIPb6aD7f6eT8pxRXxudjeAJ/nvTfHsqmpRwsFlpUD7ERkxRhJHBAEhSTxHxg6fl2nHz47sKUHE8OjQO1B8odEj1DubD@cg5PMjyX37nzZcoCiynDmiB8l2WXkLdLFc@uHR7S/jTG94I@lRMqKP/wswBcWt44@xDZZ22hGDfdecBglmoj0AltCwjqCrolUGQq5VroiDsHh7ZgCColAecVB4Ghgz7S5F8kcwMPdLrU2a4ZXnziZRGk/wzgy0mLZG83UrGbP3hgWi8KQEtX5/WjkqnmPHrXaWOaSzXjcXloANMgxIsXcuQDH/l8DR3EhIq6MtcSqzRj@FS35NoHH73MfxuTTfqlddVzOe4HnMmaVF8yhXyd@FPN@hTFfuFLqGgb3erGKxB5eS09PpeLFCpW9n36CtamGO/rmmqdva6hikoMXXmuhbdyQA0jUEHW44hr/qMTXfwog7vUfRWLR/VyvfQfDDizkQbxcZwejyqqePa@dn6xUG6COfDUDYMH9Hz5rvzphGu6S9WMGFonbLEQluqtKklfVIW5jr4R6VGRVROKeOp9ol8XUbOWEG3xNLiRQVUUFo7HQ9EF0slKkQxphCNa6ZrVWOXI/sS9OfrubOPcaCFT3fTxf7cncoHnGqY47fAsa6pT3c9Z2DuXxif7hLcdjEBDJ04/HTHi9XFJMlX0cxTElF9Mq/g7SNtGhFilCv16vtKWdGjoX0OlQSiVY/VV59e3eGsi3FzGsUo/4wls8/EjFBqZROmL0R5hpAkEEwZBsPP6Hc1mKFXbZomObzdv3Rx84NduDe89gq7uef7Pl0kIivNMUhLXxwjSddj5ATVYfQu@xO7@5t1jvqCsOv3dgjEWtBKL0eYuAL@G/3uHbww5IheuvO5O05TWms1vFwr9B0nU@izDwAm1/ra@DGmarQnX0LuFZI9irfUNKPUzifVY97kGyD1l@r12odGZDVc4Ut7NnNvz6e/D2uKnBo3eJIUpFVMIN0ErGvDnrgwaBWjC@zm/rzkWlqxmEI8lLLUhcHldGZHXYIwMbPbdBFh8OurJjMRrezeTv4lyYa7x@9KszCd6ljpjyNU0Lt76BTinLWE0mj@h3PXKbT9L0k0nQV/J6qtX/MoZfu9a14gwDQr3zejQguSn@6l1imPL76M4Kvbr961QCCkFtawh8TXRztefbtnhe8PR6N1gq@v4i1W5WUpUa6pqal/i3Xycr3SqJ2@r4hy9XW1Kd6XTs8rEbF5hmdDNw4fZMumZs4AL4QA@tEJldZwUlMguhhaQXFwfI5FwW54Go42o75v0LRE3@FwkOE86XFZQ7eo@vl@Ju7EiW1JNRHo5YW4FE9R0FAt@WsSrVf0JVznFm8HLUq48kDo16QZNb1DMenWk0TDDAdLkLctXreK91iuGoRH0obGoxSib0BZBJxvm6uL0NVja2/H1ZakiBwVgkRzZUbM8@HOeaDYrXZue7VzQLCv6p5EEO1aGWg0BfDux6zren84YtDmw4iBVvhHUw2jWkKUMyO6/OoJBbkgrOMS2XCLZkH4NEwGvf3DWVIk1VoYZ2rSrqwosKw9uJ48Zorq56jBQeriKSrx1soENh@awsfuaHXI8mv7l5wNLkGnt@j/TX8XiT2Lt@675CL@@N5ac6p/HyDznuGOXQojm0L1rFx5VznDK2nEPyofP9TqZTQJN6Jbg7z4PTKEvic2mVA93easG1hVBS5G2SjmrronCuSYKzFyuzArcCTIWEY78SI4amTwHPwCD/Lm5dBJsTqIp2WCzBnJMDVWYDCbiNV1no6ZuUMIbmeVHyiT5n2Tl6vj9RQrdZePrJuPqYv56R/b9vaa@o9t/0VcfbLMsrFI2qsQI/6zXCNE@@ulPkRogFk3QPdP8pXhM3/fART/fiNI1q@vHD9ldPqjBvHVX4Po/9/l7JGVd@Iqjx5ZeTem8vyxLe/FVX5syy/XMq5v6lzlXktELXafwc7S7vbXivQnrUjK7nnfohQ/aGj3@2vY/sxhI8vr5w8cGSL/Grk/c@TYFvz5Q4fW0L9G7s8cObJHf50Eh4bIyCCSgTSKH6ruUezC7bB7Bdo1CUD4430iJFo0IygE1kwn9QgymY9tDNXJL1MIv1TX@1JGY6cdtHpLs7VQHuuSsQrtdb0Oe2@8L52Kt7Vy9STOg2OFQJ7zh03pbVL0fbIFllz8SN43cUazWYdNy4@mqogFgk6C/phjeH/sJEO/pJYq3ibbsGw/xtWa/WX9euYjfJ@l5@7tzMX4cw9vWFIh3mN7rnGgb0cplfFS5dPaeR0Gtt74jInec3@fgXWna@nIJs4v4f4bdtBXa2CUk/zFlSd1tGeyFGIGn7eS8Q7amqmTYmn6I9cOUKO3mOSeX6@YfsNtpL@mjfTj2tj8mjY2H9dG9mvayGbjGlmzLJUrR@evRVY03tQ@xJehL94VXhCFtzt1Z44zWbeEhdcwqPP78Hqs5fxPswJGdgh/NPzZEan0oP1eLkc/gXTi32OhL0La4PDw8egMJyqF8qOGhy5A@wPH53P2i7gxYqrwMcVvSs81tviz2lmaDPAhQzzfYe97tuomec/DJIHSKu@517Oufp5CqWlxjPhLkJk2tRI5de8OhrcphR1oOcQH47xUvgcKfRUqkyjfDRLPt@yYugUDHttI4If7NY34Xq4r7YQWJiWeEHdeTOI3k/i@xy6Wgbdza8UBuN1KIkbJtmJIIkQsmA0dUDqdxiqfksyoycKnO5AJCRQ83q3HI8YDOBbXWK/nlZLrfZlX@T5o3lxL0JVxjoUXCTnxga@6Tptr4sf8iSBzNIfYQ54j0eUR@kUShXuP3BahVM7h2iJp6ZE8a8nJx2mBrGmJBSxB@G/cgv9ol/HYifC4AY53DNeuKaPLhI2184iW@5E6XN2ImUuxMMLV4iQ2PPkFgsdTe83mqPH1SjAicYTUAviMfeU48T7Op6pxbP3AqX9kfegrxSKY2Hh67k/tZPJuzdrAc4zq@5cnIFUsILoZF6eo43a4DjVCgrQdT9IF9Mz1JbGQFq@UMtdO3yllnQugr59bcieeIlXO3InzBSTkvw8SMYYDwxPY9zexV2wkmlLGR9skVqRJrKAAIv@Mm7ITEqpfy9Nhdl2HDuuIJVGvlMqi0ayLk/OzY1E9azTxRe2EPpxWzyoxpzrL@GHRtz9F8JaidjtI/fjolTcMiDfEf6VVmLR5RXA59tLTjZjdH/sHuPyBOUa0D0VrxVEWxct4wqoRKjxMg/iKLYDdDhTxYfteQEPOifFvwAXx1LifLx7UBjSNYOIK7xqTeuFm4ixAB/GS5mPXqFZhh5cl3Kt/o51SExBid8r1YkfMYhQnLa@x56krMT5j4JiEdB98jGwh1Ux1S4axdt5Rgfwau1/g5iQXhKiHU2h4Ivpb6QhW3dJxs1IWbyvNN7Vyw/8UcebFON1olO5q6JsWgmtGgvOTl87gehKNMaXQt0nvkZA5djY2rDVDuZriQ14z3ZELNFrBiG5/T66N1jsunZ6Wjk4rkjTRgL2F05V6LOb87Uzt@VW0B6zGqohbvxjs9rNkJPvLq2QUPR1CpFs0GJF3Id1a1osUQUKbxkOR5xwvDkj78dqyqSAxjlYuw3QIUtuYBmYWNQzkApHuinReD0h/qkUd03U6Mm06v7YwPdLEuaWpZvtJaY3/CYHcjwyvzMnoylxccGWOYivZqZ9CoveDGMvE4U5uV8aDPxQXziSWqY7CQf5i6o6Wg5ELz/AAFM/2nJvs5Ho0MnDL7w37/fAg6M@H32zjjZhO98oVgM3/Bw)

Like PyPy and IronPython, Jython is separated using identities of numbers ([try it](https://tio.run/##Hck7DoAgEEXRnlW8ckjAoKWJKzEWk/jDhJGgBa4e0eae4sbn3k/p7PFbCmPAOKn1TMjwgsSyLWRb55zBV90rwK@wdV@1PbjhGBeZKWulYvJyU/BCrA0C56ou5QU)):

```c
#                     when -n is -n?
1    CPython3         -256 ⩽ n ⩽ 5
391  PyPy3            always
394  IronPython3      never
450  Jython2          -899 ⩽ n ⩽ 100
```

Cutoff numbers used are `a=222;b=9;p=2;` for PyPy3, Jython2 and CPython3 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## 257. HTML+JavaScript (Chrome), 11930 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]//\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;p
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=257</script>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dint 22$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50) );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=  (^);instance Num(  );(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dc@NKdiD4XJj9B/uSAnWLgEiABCXqgxRZpQ/qlu6tKqkl1a17m2KxQBIkUSIBFgFKZKlU0d2z0eseO2Y9Pb0T7faOb9sznrV3JmK8EztrT4wdE2G/TjjmyT@gPC8bjg33P@g952QCBCmSUrXtiIVEIJF58mTmyZMnT34d1Eyv/ctfxvBix25n1Oq4PvMtz2eNvn1p9XW2O2KPTdvLZlYlCaF2@q1B13J8LyfFmMGYY12xQ6duN8CP@e6F5djvrD6EZRjr9d1W3@wyv2368GJDLLZvdd533/us7na7ptPwAHKVsWMTApuD@gUza57fN@u@7ToQtMbYC6djdmsNkwGE1e/1LZ/QZxmgqF9QnMmQdcaeuX3PwuTrlue56LnB2LbV7fmjIrxsAoTZt92nO88/n4q8xdjnJuSs17GGU3kx0uylbfUbUzEMg311dnAw7ZthX2quww5u589YZS/6ntkxp/GvsZ2B7x760/5ZttOyHJNl9C09Mx24znb75q0oG6xvmY2m3bF026kzjbWtTs/qM/RhTbcPVeZbnc30Zrq6M46p1zHu5jhwCm0huJjZb3kQ6F5a4LSgJnq21WDNvttlpuNdQUrGVnoMj2i3JtmhDhkERmNvPIjdsJjn2L2e5fNAKK7Vp2BImXVs50Li3HfcdxuDuu20AM4CuvYGPpXJk@oQrch6god1dLAYUYGDQRZO3a4VrQsPmBdy7fWsut2065w41tC3HA/K6@nMhrq7sjsd1rA6EGGMvZ5knssGXsSr1jHbel2XkLiYCutedJjN6r0e40FQDMjSQXqTWV33jc3eQXin7bFhr8s8uwvBft1tNi2LvbN6bYjOug2p4UoMrnpvqmTh27IFMI4Fpds7/gbo5iM5nSZkrcFqETjIB@WZSmw6LpCvzxyzy7mh3htR6QFNGKPpujr6N1zLc@I@u3L7F6xm1U0sNibmWa2mOehAinYTqwP4wPZY14UnVKLDIFsQ2UdaIG5MTJpZEEwmqF6rBw0Tq9dFdoG6Dmr5qm8Cf/Q9UY@@3QXusP24xyzTs1FiQRTPchrEGb1QlrlQ2mils0sbGh6QYtAn3J7VJ9YnvAxLASjNkFeVq77tA0dgKXbYsWX22VnfslTOp5ZXN3vIpdEkITEXU/CxIDox5vZ2vHR0EAcG5TF0swcM2V89@84Xksn0Aluu5uFXkOW8VHq@z66Xz9HNZSYwca@vmCorfGBe6vzcgt/QqKVa/RsJsEpAlQ5LuT0/ZWo9yKDmQwZTJjrRpV1m9F4nkjDbnqqDSLPhUA2oDRAC7Ksklaw@6PdRuo@Jal5AoTuu0wJ6QmH7A4dX@XoaqgD4r@ElmXVpIQ/wOnKviMJnbeAQ@AfQiGThHQ4RFLocaIqCokG6ntsZEBzE9Hxsj0AViIoYD5vsK9Y07Q5GgXBExXPdtzxgTowzcBpY813bsRo6C7JBUqcPbfESkjMBKXlAa@hGZAtlCoChIlwqKgZ9/M3fbrRagGenXnf7DcGuXwGz16lrNCmz0LkxZFjXMTuULYBLYuo8OiRwaXbsBkk50xmJJCgTlOqVO@g0GDXUKxuaXNsEYWuBgKj7Fmdyd@BDHpOsa15wiWhzzoWCd80aVCwlQGlTsTX2eA9qqQ7NnHhG6w785ibTeiUW91KvlEc55dHSuQWZU3V1ZTmVauWB4fQV8oK3@CLO@WpnoqvwfNNz7YbUG/lt18kwrc7kesHtWY4Sn8ART8b7tbiqo6RW1LxdqOtN22ko8W3gxSIkHFfz9UK9bOcq@ano0SQBzRWiweZqKXVVRlFDjeIy1QXlQgdJ9pUmXJEw16siyTFYj3gjYab9LrlHjFQX5EsXGQTkkO51LKunpHVDRTGBcDPLjQGzSjqFQxQ4Z1cS8Vg8ES06YYCSThQUG@uZ7aLY6vTaqG8AURyvBzK3j7xbN4F7POzUfFDpkqxGfE09IUgWkolXVhykdg0EacBH1CR5k8P4GgpKgWHchCZbstWINGQQAtCWfe@WNO64qB1QnrDnAdHhYKJmC6oGIvOC7PCC8JTIZ7JIFw4IFMRWs9imVrOhEWBzA5kueD5SNgBfzXAYwMYbSUT2dM0R9mpcNRg3GOzTTNYF8dAfsbqFMgeEj8U7FExkQO3PA72XuU2W1jLZ7GQbu9XE/H5qR/suCOl3qYUtCQsfbUwoaFgT1OyO6bQGZgvkhetAFLNet3q@EFRQEs8HUTTd35CnJjpP3WtLy4@n06ZOJFCPxmmgkOe1J7pCE6WLUNs10MlQ9eNjAdaw@yCWoCefSh0ALqcSl18jyEQGXstzshBoAMBk1tCqD3yQasDAV2273gaexdw5XC7yTmg6efCKpg6SXWuGSWNmjOLDjKSnQi/MxlwUGtbobTzQuSKq4oQHVX7UYzFm0@vOQOyGWYSOIOKrp0wdeO8OnF3XcWcgBUKGaBFkMoTXA2hip6gUQ8cVqF3UWENNOawiqDOQGtDygf/avt/zctBP2H57UNOBU1Jn/dGhf@Qgs6T8/sj2Xe6uddwaiGUP2mcqSCFVH9Ts4VSByC@swzeedAkKWNNjBei53w6A65R40wOBSf57CBwJkklwEwp@lwGQgHQglNL0SBQfgFA5HTl1RZ5gSjnJZGy7sgoOjBiS5gtU3iaz@Qa8pnOJYNHM6CmESnn9Ojm0iE6K6BGcsiU9mCjaPfMoPZBluDXNjmfB0xl0Ovg6cLiUU7iuoLJr6cEDEG0KJWd3ex27bvtVHsoePhQ6BVuCMR6qTU3UmVSI80AMpnUQKAAjuh8OrfvuKSm7igoFeXAzkbDV77t9nq7f7rtXjDwQTIoSdc/tonRnL0nhQg0ahrW2g8N70ZdSV2rOVCHCPpX05Xhcf@PajnIdX1paiufiRegxl5YegWsbXY/QlQDXI3Jp5EI4HV0UI0kuDC1TDPSrxG/KAeahWsHmMMTe/p3dU8xyLrdaSZplQzwz@FSBztBjALSGD8ATVwsFdKqqXLyCguq15mTp97DXO6337Z4gwhfmpcnfBRVWiQxQcW4fBwZ5VF4W06Rb6IN2AYOBelvpx8/L6fPK@fV5I3F@E09ibDVvFmpQKEhP6eqtvjsANUQtr@U0o6Kq5VVQPmqFeDq@oiibGgzjYCSifrapJkxObSVuQW@onJ/HgaiCPuV6u0/4hsmMqoakgnygwgO6thLXrzch/ZpaURNxiKvGkzB0K8TjQJk6EsGjQmNbmiDQ0cmXnDB7iYREzRtGpfi71Z2CHw56J6MfD969Q9nFcdRCDusMTK7l9QRA6tAJYHUMnBq0BkG1JkM5OpHG526Tj4r28FZ6eiBZQ6qtz48OSicFSqZtehegU2gthE2BrgxU6Td0kAadQcOSZsGA2ABXfZwTnDvAxFv1OtNcRmBanWci0l3U2RxsIGtI8XSZ1ulOFsFrQ373JspASMifYi7SX@pBljj4zDyFSR6AxN47fToxRda9AH2C1b0OKt9anxcAXlMr3LNBj3CMkWOHNEZzQMEE3gL9shHOBTiuo6EsDIZzbjQhPiECEOSH2hZqEvYEDCJu2kMYEsdwPkWo/qixova/5zowOLX0lyQNZQaCHGerLH2m/n/MFSm97o1bJ2j64Ox1zDrI@0l05zI7B4QggVKp2SFq/hbi6cEBjePvKiOoUnXTQfo1bBqnDmyvjeSFsQT2Av0mUBUHqTi5Q1Q7ZHXQcltAaWto@3zUCi38FKM8MT1FxXHSDh9nIJehjoyZCmbuSIF16zDCt0BXxlA@XcJKzqXddx0ksl4C1CCK8lgHU8hnkRfYaGfnMLM/n76zkAPFbnkbEdpGsU4Tt@5B63Lcjtty2QoAIGvqOmfsQwdnOGGU45s9aFH2OyLQTsuFof4kD1pWOGe6vhqON02ETBG8/gZ6ATa70GOAOWU@PfxuCdQQI5tOQ/6DtzRdYSEjWKbLiJ51NgYQqwAd5Busye9avfaoP8FOnivmTXyaPKSGyWeyTFAhIVeihb@jqNFGzn2gnQdBjcA1q@wlGhPg5F10XD1R@glthTcbKGFsyht9A1JMIL1V4eP6RcF1npqQW@FUgdbsur6Z@koHEY03CTVkzWayl4ovxVOahneZglimyFIN6zKFUmqMeViy6jNxDy2rnsJQ7NxY4JhJniBwDmnO4XLoBsXkz4AGYczp8rcSCRTslLswbZ5p6OTP2gNLsuptl8nnMMSIlkyGDqINY2UNKA8KII5LwmhiRUjy3QEM6xpWx@7a/iHN2XccHLvoJLx1lFoidA/kzRjBsW2BQs4nHMadDM6rj/sop8XhT0CSE1YY4uucpH2rkVoZY3vmun0YV3rMoDmFTEj6rghIuV6voftDQMBjlah/94J@/vnRfql6vHP2pJAaeP1Ux66BjGhY1S4MZjvQHOZcmDecISwB79iO27WhRAHKdxedE9f1ufKACwf3u2IYMcDxdL/69HD3ZOfkG5E56tHt7qBjYh5zy1MAIY5TglmIpu7WXNAtnMFcTKBcHO0ePQ2wfPHi6eFOdb90fHQWQfNm0LFNY5jqXbTmFegLBGGGnuakP@o0Jld0aJg6MYsghA2OufIMxqZM0@CuoR9PFEdlOgagiozdo6bhLLCJ89x9ljHSW1uNmrm5aa036mtrG02z2WisZYzNbHMzm8mm4baxvmWx9wSuadaQZm7AxWdFcAIJ04DM08PQ1wINB4aiddBYRjPzFYYuyFw9m7U21rbMrfrW1paZ2WismpnNDcta32iupdPWupFu1jaNzdWFmYtkA1Wr8VuXZoCg1eFkAQWC8FPgMdEceOZB17tijUwms17PNrdWM41seq1R20pnNxs1Y8OsbVnp5tqqkTEa9YyRC@LijCpIiTZUGGqVDqimQZBmQKAqBZ1ptIpplTFYhhYCZ3kVRUwvWEbGgYMIWMOAgVhExqlZ4Z9F/2AJGadohP86@ndxAXmsydJr6CkANwkQ15H1fi3w3ELPcAV5Ym0VRKWQn7PC50cSmK@N9A0iv8I16Ej5rg2D/C/9ZnPCO0PeFxp2ZZ2x9yp58xXoybVfUdhbQTOBQ3xrhI@vXM/EdytoJnCIL8vx4Yr3bHRTIbNAQ2TrhAxXyGfimgqYARhi2iBM0VX1cdgmhc1bUhdpzQyeGynEvUW4@Wp59Q1fraiKxXLkZt5AzkATe@qC/vzUxnn75kSLkcIR@LkkB9MIkxNJ45DMeJmEaZez13fkKCIuDGznwqWBc@iqpnUji1hCFN2Lzu2YTRhq0G0C9Fambofw/qtba9JtBgB2utMzcxRA056i64eu1kyd0AMnQGflYHIqdyL5mtUcwCgoVbMddN8Bpm1tEmSzVrPngQIlcPNB8JwBlmMnAxiJZvQ13QiGvbh0AjKbz8OeHR4RYM2kQdzk/D@bIL4/6PsQSzz/6/caUAm3q6htjmgsGDqqjnVF/NGcW2MiKr7QbXbtjnt9Igy57kJZN3HJ1eyEjtmoqfY1rW32uzjkEtUNDIo34IQFvMZzzudigufsRHKMiDy5zsAcu8vqM6AJdmpJhCdGg@yOazaIDHwobFsUqY@VzavBGvJBYUThgZ5nXkIzVi7YeKuA3x74A37H3QF3VaPdw9@iJiog01mzZligIps121pQ6X3zYtBwNdD0qMiYsfUZsOPS02Sd1uyYF9xZRefs4vMC9u1WC/QJ8ZwHdtWGsQ0NSlNX9LiLLzxn4PW0GlSWDw2H3qgpdBek0O/w@zwQW@yfCx3zqWZ36HaPSg@Zi9gFVDoiNG5p0iJEs6fI3DFrIxyqtz@dyzBBUnBA5hTqiUR6Fbu9cO03uhVpfnzsKyn@1tbs2HwzFSfJrOFVim@i0vgEMpVZbKu6o2Kh47K7ZkfLNCLOuRI9mDoeu2aA0ryNVu@YHrCWL6rDuoTqo9sidseeqQ7Drv7YtYDZx9kJtgDMW00WYku06rrbsT1s2p15EnR6AW6cJm5no1tkStqeRdgG6UxeWwtds@WCW/dxKXcOo91DyvFVVFynjnCO7s4jWt29wt9c1aLtXlr8PrujezczV/eQWFqHWMKuz@xRGvW7OBW3A9FtNh0vZubLr3dm@k@2gWCKIzpAuydfe3bH9dgp3ReRpdWHaPw@m6OjFLRNR6P1oKh7djSRqR7TxSzrnHo1Oy23s77ZSplwm1v5g34T@wTxvK/0C6WXYdwtvQL9yHUM8Zwr9i9S/Yu76o6WJvq4aB9xLuiBZ4kwsSg5v4AwksCdOLMLd5DepJh6io@X51VAv96@MkfB81foWeZRN@hZeiPSt0H9wwhbm@Dw@1wH/1VSW1ucWuN@4ukW2o27ChGp3IuOBR0Z3W9VKcukjU@MYaTT9xdWzc7AGlgzZdVR7Y2F@9sXjELun6m0KMaymO3EGSGc6wyh3onx471yjX04vi0UMGbHhkZ@p6YzU971QEfv4ZD7GBzH6LgdseUMehOVOzGKc04WU67dC1q225jIJIZ8qkTavFufmlDkPYt@CwdXfDCIa1uF1XQ6LfSbyPz1xMuiQddqGPeNze8TCZPPOOUxLM6G9CPO2WmMp1Kh6u0LT8NJzftJp8y8GQEC3tpKObZj@SO8z6uSWdK25rqdT6lCELoNG/U30Epx4eeuqrylG4ndYGw89@HhzEmtOW/Wg3dIYnQK1MOB9yJuiE693quaNVyyhlbamnpdPA8Umci9KxXo5mlyiW@d6MxXPMWMiqFv6hsLWyRXZ92a1TH5Y7i@tgjflr66EF@osgg9mda2cD2Mr4CNV1RjU3KrNwJi2Q0Y5LStrkWvC0YHZuPNwAsec4GGLv5mBOu03jgvXs8GQeHgfWK1LaJK@a4DwzLf7LcsHNd0cFVc@M4TzsGs@kziHnbNlsXPVS2SnuOpDtw6zEeDY@fsSY8c33VWh2h868diVoDGdGGNvOA5E@GzUR3qc9C9e6puqt3XaaPSXQ1dT81cTLhDV3TabttpW22@Eyh8m9c8gCN9fiJuUSEg/612nZF8iu5SilK243Y696EsykcuLV23OTNPJTyn1YCon4R3ZNYgQDzunAKEvp4IRJ3@vHbTtgbQZXmu7/Ysjd7mgXZwsojf50nRYHHnV52FWjhDABQJnr8q/jvHpi3T9Xs9elR7nYFHN4qq0fG6WVV5QMnchytsn2874nxrtdxavW3flaWaZfqOfZEKZoT468KRbS9CBZtp@@itd2wgXn@kIzcUouGn@DicV6Vicol3W6Fjdh3n2N6g3x8hJXzXZV7HvRrLh8n9E@E0Ll99QMe8HIiVwRnBpA3gzrpgB9mCJRCxkDiXwUgJR4Vbs9KgsBhzZ5QmtndGWsfqKr/N04umyk@ZiqzffsqUqNj2QJODdmTmFvwn@GdiMXpmZ@W0By3vtrjjE/YNULHwNrOmd1p4pnmqonmlQg9kOuIxj96ZTgq3b8OzCjU3sBaurmQXLq8QnNHRTNeGRxUeUIeDudNmHbvn8TvTmpmZCsPtJeTbUKPZw2ZRPw2ryddC0HWXptd1@3iICFQKrd63vDpOpaNE5voTlz6O2wLJrHXYGDiAnVmE26vWM6s/7PG0r59bLRO3Vz61cadlZwZXANbpxeu7kH5nYHr2dwaub83EN72AfRe6Z2bLrj@ZoHyALKCo2IPHHxNsj163iX/Vtj06vxE4Fsw5IZNxtkU@q4K@P2u0NjVdHx6MXjytElGUxN5vph2yYI946MAFAww3Z6Y1aybe7dG4cUSuRZPwtk8zs@I5k6tmbwJYlPzVoNsbeOIxO3XapxOdou5ekL93ZYNY1N6CNGZts@PPnsaOzMyCziU6ybFznhb@Xbvjtth3N9MMVDTotFEpn8Fwu9BdH5s@tAhnBgNT2vdcKMVJD63PC/YWeMJaZZrt2P7iCR7fN2GMFDyxMLyzwVOIqad41x9/KgbtbDZFni7UYKBvH9U7eCj@U0cCXOwCF57SoXV0hufmo3wvkrH2BMKgd3Gsq@h4beGiTw67VNcZ@Bru8l/Up6wv7FNybLi5HmENpnyn9OyFGuUQ2v56lx5qwUBw4HVGY9fcjQdTjGc7oKzNl8WT0MFoYt8ikwYntFHzjjg7PTw9RSJ/35014jkeQe9z7yETdCCD7r5Vx5XHO9N@7j4D1Q26sh4I3e6JhVsGpmTJ7IgY7albNztAn8adyZwS2hl9xXhwbfasGtRvZ@yarYvNQrxv@uYc3YkmDmkEGLru5BW7U7P6b2hGMOKeN6idzNATa0jDkPkMw1uh5tfrXOHGabmJNjK9tuP1XNfhdxLCaXgYzxYLG@ge6Hb/FXcd9y9P9H4zB2mTpT265NtNrAY/uDevuH2r5nb4HYswRxw4Nt9cYPZty0s9tZ3BkPyYBrrb7GEO38ab1jdwmsNrQ2O7smGMHe7uxc1qfKuwNzWSApX40vRoyX/2mGZiJ/H9dxW1zX7dxbUz4fjElbPIkbA75Hi4VZpvTahBpQxBoJn1QWBX4I6sdrq1Lt3mjkkiNX1i1fDIXY3Oj/rmcJYSOXl0THhOHd4KRBo2/HWmHMOoR727I5sesk1S3O7RjQT61Uw2CZJ7blv1d6Z6hywNWxHNJadMGtHObEiTm@BAzelYmt/GPZYp358nMJ7bF4PGPda6ggWUQdfCNevJlZu5TOV6beIId/YqfShw@5bYuo27BKHpB26UutrOXJZF9PB/tPtFCjrm6voanuAfDLUWiLO79wVA5gd9Rzzuw3bHruc37eFRD804uf158gWLlYUo8ODNAV0r8woB9ekMOny@oxXZ0dVt0PgOtMGmC64OiXDf0iznUiMTR8NgubJvBnZk5tbh9OZQ447doVdeuB4IAVrPo2eq5x0fPj0603uesWDmEDf8DewOru5RVgI/KCC55k9Rn9JetcX65v7RbunpDlMaIGRcR70DWiyI9tpmzfLNlDl3nIOhlj9b6Xty9uxpYnxomSl77b7btUjvEwdwyFZQaFXCS4qjYeBn98Xxc08PDF@Jc3QkFoMTHeBp1usDnMEB1tIZASqKmUioqiRiPXGvWBet6mAkj46DXti9PEsHTqREG3o@gscD8QpbNtl2gWXSaaaqeW5bAsgGdT@w8qxpB6h3PM9uOZCFIAdkFghNhnCLQx4D9doP8JbLbPl6mEvnjBtWYHJOZpUKzzFelEhp2CObPic8ennZrBSW45oWX46fOzmWjofgVgeGlTPBzQlYyCw@RIZD@nJ7Xy4Z6wqpmecmUUDco7mhtuk0OhZ74dByKpS/zw17cKsxZ7hN@C/@oCGsMJG1sa7tmR0gCBpSg5puu1ePeLoBuXo9E604IY6rNk4BY@ra3g6D4alfb3PjS1BdLw7ONoVJF2G1DV6O@SRfmAvOObjSiMdTfc4YPDfhUUORcBgrKBSMewZdBxSNht/2dHZq08nTQX98lkTYsnP8Pi4nNJLskDUs3JFJB4pp9azjuhd0yAhz8hd/wA3Z0LFicdwzSJ4MWEVSxNPDBlmPqdfdAeQ6QPLO6rsCREEim3V/gGvVZD@N/FU8bEsWdoDbtcC@DCXDjczs7ZwyrcTiaJkN7UHk7aayvHPy@VfldKXwgXVT1n/9Xkq9FoSTP9O21j05yQKQ/A0yVjQ4C8Hj0DiTl4cyTzA8c22Lkc0Vrw@0KseZDI9dBzzmur2g2aCqTCaxQm4UpiYUdFM9B4ZmumRejBjWuiJDM3S4z0HZTebtPGhg8KoSat7qCsvKgC@faqc@y0KCaKzHBBc3SEankNFoCkZZHrL3jOQr6MpGNg1vnJAdtNPTLewG@/VXo@coUvtWbUB7iS8zeiZboOIsVwvbRXJBX@yivazyq/NhJq2dDzdKFdD@BVHPz4efpTNfA9XdPsR6mMKWV3q@f72sF9Pv33vmiMnyTTzPz32AmFi@Pj48Lp2e7Zy9OIVauAlE2wE//RXIGuQiOtDZdjtkiQzogmr4J8if8G0sBtHWpapK0aN3BCpoLWvyMndGRNNE7Duiz4rvWZHw2wBCpjVtJoU9A3CBScyGVMPCD3poT42JuMImFHGZjf0HNqCQMHi6ZoYsJVLJrADE0oBY9yQVm1/YR9zvPhS7E8tisj2aCYIUC9Mrh@G8iDNJcPP3Uu6e6Xl/93JzLIvLTTALyg2goW8Q52Dn8OmLk9JktKCTJ6lb2MqKM6dcOGNL46p8YASLTD2IiLj8XJCZTBH4q@jMuClOy7@yoFhCONa7PDJxKOVflsaMCZQpoDXYitBCFIVygPoNKiLTR2JBz45kMeijI@iueRFDIXAgh6iDjOuywBwjq6Y6XkExEKsgV9D0jkmIC3kd96LqTzJocVg07KMHHm9zc7qqsNfxGPxHeqXAlamwIRPdmVFhGsvAr2M5LShwAKvmeR/Fljkh5GWedznML1qjhDw13pi04kNHPcRRUuilO2bPC5TBGHvu@laOvR24ZK4iECahfkGGUE1uPJaqlptEJTMYMMQG9Trotwjf4cFpAbUzrpqRfI/y3MDBjgqAuB1XcaDc76O9Y37SlxtU5CR3he2@oKukWRNP2OoKtQSPXdqeDWN@qoQm6jgdkJRYGlFwtAVMhkrYTscDnaQB3TdoKD52taCc6HT@kB9C1Bwmx4An9VBlTDJZQlivcNuWG3SlVzgKfM0jLxMcYfYiOOPbS5oGlGvZTmD4N4eWgGnCIMf8/gC3Fxbjt6IEWciRS2v73U4EcIZVy3Mr9fE3f5tbsjz3wf0j4R6md@Ht18VbE9y/EYQYBrz9s/AtA28/5m@vUlhlt833jfMZWmKYe2ITmPOxfKtgKBgCE8hUoLDKsbq/OjxmXh0t62KFds1hpK5QzATjFGZ3gTMuqaIRnKcwrscxHqX8FfAJMBcwCeo4qNZQela/oqAlt1wqhRnHhSCd9nlaQ773ggy7vR2gQVPQxFLr2fU1IwWZ1C4DhGRrpoXHzjhCVc2BYJQu7V7hda3Otre3mezVzY5VWM9zBkktm69W5ddhRpcBVuKjhTKDOBBlHAPCiiKasmwmDBWjYm8WN@Io2Bou5zdQCRVyAIiK3k5gnQJ0TleQCpjZsYY@qU2jYBQEUttxI5aMA0QaIOK40ezmdJscHyXD2ctIK9Wj1SC/RDAavufkWRxbfsXO/XOnIsyvMuC@n8/gXwfc/2SGTVbOWWh957YxUGXalCeWhj0@dVycBD6A3DIlk8qspox1NcKhskAF@cX2/h5QQgsHiVG37Dduz9vZKx1@cXR8essoFEHGp8HiLF7cTpxrerJcCR3xMN@TRN09SJ0@2z0ISBnN1XgaFiHG@2qnszkrtemczkn9JT@1dzttCriVkJG@L2Kaw9EOaH/6bezj0FQEcI8fGrqVqqJe35Qr28VzJ3Yr@fezDP3G9BVkLnCde2TmNz6dTcxiaNT/DI36e3pwJN3A8@h4UNF3L8an24VHJICDB1hAAkh6KoCaJzwhA0d8BmhshiXDvyrgkejjs0RkfjXMUQTyLPj@ADatsdVAYS6vbXrtjl2ToANvoAlJbuwmsOYSmsnRvV7H9hVVoimQAqpBIMQU8RWCYW6o0@qxQsZ@CVeSLbLAF@BTJWgEgC9@PPDa7NjtRea29q3AdQLaCNsf8KVFi30x6AJckx4nFopYC/QTDSIDoeJhVvmoGlqWMMA3TKCRQ0ivjGb4RMH1biOrDFW9bQ0bdgsEuKImoaV/ZoBaFZoIwEKTUT4nDjKOU/hzPKwVJekn2WEcjpGbZVO3nYY1VNCwUK4C@in6x69eXsZV@RYPkDHIvcB83JRVyKAhmr5oEWOLilONbSv89MCU2c6tLTTOhNYOoFogxVO//xSc0D8pza7ZY8qAzJV6TGf0qpwrTtLz@yrTitziicMSCRpVw4MCQGtG0Ca5iHGYgvOQSqoAtYO@ntPAxzu7x8qGrlfATYmobBln1PagK8e5KFWCURJEyRHaAtYty2GOOPfqnPMgDoZLZD@Noc3OGcFkZZMm512kBZWaFR9G7E6NWyCn6tZWTtTGpKjZYsAWt6W8ngK0M0RIoKUCfcXhdaAaWqHHzxXg2gWIhcdfWo5jAYGAZ7om9MHmAJisryaDz44kx1bLKYUYz@ITcRoeMjppzbwUv@7gAvdyKk@TM/kb6FNfn2On2hTd6ij1P6b0VP5aWe4URilQdNSistwuGInVlURi2VlRlh3s6h8@xDmdm2XQJKo6DJGGAKQtd9Q88DNoHoVlJ79sbivLjUJmhWLAKwzSriHCBy@lXy@bN6nlh9BTJ8GnzxuvsuyRQcy0rhs3kD9sIcupJPDMNdoPpG@OYPLLdiKBedCXq5iBD6nz0wTJ7PPTFE0f5YU2mmp1RXObkqphTdz64gonoPAWFQ2CPYOCXRxCqAbAY1vmq7PC5ugePOEv8ZwXo62llhdV/@XJkPsLFiHv4mSrjJsf5RZJgYBDBYiIr0lTVUGY/PKXMWOdycryo/XVzmUink3n4WbkN1iWfbZ8nlmLsdhj0/RhyJ5auT7f32xdMquZWX@raWW7qb@tHF8cH389HKnnSjy2d/RKNtYAdINt0e@@1wbLzLnYp12x2EpKiqVWjIcbqdTr169B5cWrXNSLAYheUctavFJWNoRHt7ixsZJc31xJnjyOVyEvUFxVyWTUU2bbKXZu97xGA35um74ApMT4xR49wvTAAf9M@HWHTXIOd6xWa1AyR9zfjg3wceCLuM@@@/LlS3S8pIu9OxHxYxyjQBfLVc1sjDKZSWf@4k@WbpLXx9Xtv/h@N2Ut4eMIHz@6eYbuUyP72dLSZ7u7a2tJIBx3H3/3@JudnZ21/WT2uJx9tKall7b//M@WljKZ7UxqqeJ5RiVevvhazqTXZP0vfi9ePT7@judh3eG1ygxw4n0TfgbLZtkFewfXRZPhP7nfNSJuE9215jvsIEFZLpCwicezq/HTV3Gsn3cxwzBiI/qrUtGWmFF8tPHffnL0NubHipnUyz48/djb2PpmjDvBAW@rwdtlrBjbRrD1m9goVSgUwLnx3/49xC9@AXgwZLQNt2I2wLU@ihW1AkV5Hyuug8PIZCDd/@d735NixSFkolg8PGCZYmZFsImx@dB4SC7Hb4OCcR4zNteOHtOrbT0@ymQz2@h2LPxyShuGoyhkDCNzzkTlGaIKsbgG3rkHa4Mb69SNsQB0XOcs4CgmOAEYhHiEu4UHsQ33wOAJuJfnprmykVjLPHbyLyPXxMs/xHWCn6haX3r8ej@V2i5CT49XLvf4vCqaWYptbMqu@xgn//LsqfDN423oapoL4PA7J08NL0HA2GYhWeVEClpZEMLGbyzqFRO0ZGGD@hXgSnj95f/1lz/9y5/Q30/p95@lWLABRStfVorBBRwkF/vy9bl4dZ6xZ/xyHPiHX/CKPugBLkfMTcbCq1jEG/2LN3LRc8pPhBTDF4IYR5kLxwKJRelKsQ@pFMthLV0Wi9HywJUKX6kYPOfkeBYp3bh8ojwgGh89WoI/@ocrfMX7EvkIbwK5fS2x4oJrcR8gxcqxcqXCm/V0iRZcJzpynS7eqtFe5VKKaSCoEokT4FImmBuu88Qd1wv46XpVvKX0MdaYFPt7v4oSi13DVUloNzfl@JobX3cf668S@bz4Bz0vH77hxV2Qw8qNpm2/KiYSZcppuSiyvK2xSpEXgO569dU2oE9sl7cL7h799CrSS6u8Kpa3JyNT/Erx8eMEkvYxICguVxgMLaA2brZvijfl7Zub7W3436b7jXiC7832rX96jK85MOPwCtb/eTlVPE@JVlmswLsOTA0@euocuRueAFcuS7Fr5BxWrpBdt4JWNtazFY1RC1kB6ZXKGSuZ1VR2@Nl6KQNCwEPwjCynVtDxHrtLUHi2pBgOHbb4CGKLPF5//Pb/wN/5x2//LbxC1vADehRae4t/T9/h31sf/87q@HfyFv/O3uHfiY9/xx7@PavhnxQrMAYa2/KjdCd9mTYujAtw2CwNCnM73TYa0NmwtMXSo/SIpbuu0QCXBX9pcNnpJku3WNpJO4YBgeDwWdpHVxMeLfhrApY@/NnpNCJPXzJIpYNdGNlDpuf7KlPPpTKLv7ZAzdINPa2v29VKdr33thyv5GOp8/MU1z1ZZi1P9q9vbhirVkvP96vVFDL/@TP3aPx/dNSNvi787x65z47crgv/R0dHz85BgBUTjxPaY7gKxcS2eDyKFfOPznMaMm7AwrHU9qPz4qqG7vUEcGUG/RKfeI0xwrO4dC7B2Pzly6s89bP5q8v8VZ4c4St3VAWAAOMOiJUX/TP4QLzzlynqUa/guiS89IbOKwgMXNyRenl1jhokjBfCfyBH9PXv4d/@/9f/sxdMKVdUaATXN9sKXSr@qer1zfWNuBdVRREvyjb8oQe8Y5TrmyI6CegaXGVFrag3N9wP7oq6zREWMY3tIkUeA4KkiIVpUrr8pvz9PjFtfp3HQU2CkbQilgHPz4fptJqvgU@4FmC@pxUlNU97bZZruAoIo0dDJYjsWj5vrHB3Zi2Tz6@Jl43NfH5TuJcVZev2VUw/MtbXc5m1NVXN59MCFsaJ@cAJKCzPrOexkedjKmaWt3wljbOR9OWLuJyTHz5UxLdSHvV66sOHxlb6/fvQq1pt2P1qFf1X37@XqzJuyylsZeE9vfn@PQiduOr2lecuXxBWNIN9lilSCltuH0q1AcHMSGXGabZNz/T9vvLO7iVl3O/oySpZq06n3f55/Bc//v73z@MF3KhBvmsGIsBUWHZ7e32tWFxfA/f6JhRcXuY7f5RWYstQb5ZTMi8uk5fjMRFkbG6o5HsTx3AW22aPitBQPbzY9U2M6o@tZVWlNrLUa/AJ/IytLe7J1taVzcSW@Cssqay4wsRfuVxeTaytbKw8roB6c/tCoZq/NgvxVCp@U7g2czhrdZOvi68i4Ekk8@HD1S0g5mY6fy5Vq/s7ZztV/KAirslD78fQkyS0hOutvX68TFOM2a1KGQtWSaXO4/Fc/jFVvLGZZbF4XkBqcZD3bHOLKBDzPMlu4qHEIeGd@q3EeszYWIWOFfpVqUcbpDbSrIFrzH3mNptL4Am1x2q4HcCzOp3gWxJXbr/TuLIb1pIUO366s1c6S2ZAR4llDnb2kpnTF7sxA1@z43cMZrFV9Dgp7ewfvYAYx09LO6elzw@/Kr04Bn9PevPOtCzTGljWVXUwuHqL3xuwqlYPfMdX1arbnvnmjdmjC8YpXDxfXX38@Q8//vx/@vi7P/74uz/8@Ls//cW3P/0h/P4Afj/mzx//u60s3n/x7T/7/Y@/87vg@Z/h95/g9ye/@Pa3vsd/9P6n8PsvEb8/Fb8IHP9JgOvXf/HtT37vF9/@xs/g9y/F72e3f7/5J7N/P/3B/B/G@8nvL4b58b@H3x9yXAHsj3@H@@HzFvzvcLjf@NnHf/Ef@P@fiz90/u7Hf/GneBMv//Rnf/5fPn7/P2Yym3/@bz7@8Mcff/CTjz/4/scf/OjjD/5x5uNv/RsjHb39/sef/tF//@M//O9//L/Q/x/Q/Q/v8//xZ//0r/7Pv/q//@qPxe9P4PcfwPUnf/UfgVf/5o9@jv8/@aO/@U8/x////V/9zR/9r3/z6/@aHL/NHf/vv/x3/P7X3//hX//gn//197@dc//hwvu39/D/9h/A5/75vA@e@5TrU32@/ZXy83ehxjgV4AH6sgPLgB67O7JoxuKzYU76jMWKK3iBWC5vZjYTK6CCrmxtgWyukP82gjAJ2ulP/8nH3/o1YP9/Acjg7X@GN/jnLxD0I3phX389EcgSNAuiJb7@GgPFsPHrKNSPwON9ChTy9OP3APE1BfOLhWCQ7v9GYADHBFgAN5kBgsFtntz/F9/@89@jgDAuev/aBMp04B2FXkbw90FRf4TtflyaKPSPUHR8/Pn3Pv7eP/7489/@@PNfx85BW9tK7iShd1880QuA2XvAIeD6feAA0MBhIwzzl6QMOJa2cXJSMhKvX0Pul8AFo64VKbsKb5JRJLeBboiYgDdCMhwm8A7/0toWwxfwGZIvPFkCgnYT@MXvhDQsQBiB4qfCGTqLm@A1xOmFAuDFSDxOsroJ4xk23CUsELOQOGHVlcKQR0ygR5EwINtI6HUiGxk5sVnYhwQLw32GuBB5QnoNz9eF4mZhWER0HygLgCOxC0kCFH6JPDEsfoD3AuEEeGm4/wGysllIJIqb4FPAQiYotWSV0jSyVDgqe4JRudGfMdxu@egxNBnZ2JT59AeQkglovCfG0AgI4BB@nlgRxaH/wEm/FYwP9TQk@nA/Hv4IvSm@AAC8moa79OCnaZibxxA85KgSlCw8EhwDUC5BilSAEjxIY0lICarfBL1A@pCHT7u2UVQgOizO8vIyuLaL8qpcPYJhJIzX@hc5zzf7uIpIumSOyetbMnrjlie@mXP5mMabK/srcDfgv7REG5ipLPkVaTmOMxdxnjVIS0usumtujBcjKCO9rVAREgTIPoMQ/D1@DG6gET3HfjjZQP8J6VVMYjGqe2gsSX6Hh14g/0hTIo9XBSkxfqcZbR5D15N6MimeOj3JQxcOnULFU18mlZHxoQ@tVTNjfY2pkkLf1FKxhuoWqWPSM6@16w5h2JGU5aSxjutPqpiqOctlsLVKpVwa7t@4uVzhg7G2IcGT3gf4bS/xlSngG/zCub69jfVfvNZoPgmdoLSuS8WiWHpnhlQ8LZ0B@NkRMzJpncGQ5XptI7OWXctmVtfXsxsZY219a209u7kKknU9nc1kjK21ta3NrY2bkFqPQTglcyu17HbxH926/od/NOua7YuXVPyaDXWaQ7@Rip0C3wK6jMvw8nlaztPkFtFyuZxO4l9mdRXukM@kkd2oLC11rjUs9jntO7zGjQ6QVelaw47vAVxMeiCxB@AFF6SBC5FMbB05PMqLbQL4iU6@VUA2ssDIUA/nwMkcHdTo9fV15CfFlr77XZ8VizD00A4PpBi0wTYLFsY1u6G3dfqyZmPQtyi0xdj@4VeHp4dHz/X9w1MYCXzDMqtpXYrd3Nw0w@UcerXY0dGRhMIPxnirBsa/qbPBYEChNXi/GZpSL3rle1Imo2VWtVVDM1bx/w5HBv/vD5@B/wzeIdZqRuJn8Tp4dCeYMtuStrlliWLwvXS95jZGuo2ff8HzY4VMdmNbWGsqStvC8EKR1pTLwGQV/EZbubIdmGQoSh8@fBjSNo7coeOL/RyZtU30ZxK2rIfQZT00uDO7Pnam0XmG5jOeQy1D03DYU9yW7bvszOXbf3et@hyIvbZJn6zb67swJvzVYXZN54IH7dv8HH8Y9MREQ75e1/bbcyBe9Lp4ns/q/4NhKHVrkEGsJw6wC7d@x3VnAWywF8dzSvksNLuDWz/I7g6Anxx@/uQs8jwr7ew9kdbZ7tHz/alHVgBl2dPSwVn4usFDg6jZEMU3padPp1/FA@RunqYBllh2I3AYLGb6ZkFOVuUyW6vk/ZtHxvbDh8Zy6vgpTjQc94GOHTfF2PkHbfsrrbiZ71tD3xmwF1sgBYslqGpAstcv7C43QZK3rDK0ShiDV6DUOk42dCy9WmxQK8gsS89we@mWwc9K2Z5ERxbxC2j4tUNfwlP9DfzKOc4K1fBz44Mem@sJD/RCZ99utaEvuXIDAKlmmgx@n3pB/OgcAVBpoYfP0yC/WyGdGeC4n8FusrSkc5JsbWY3t1Yzm8nNrc21rLGezSaNTNLY2NzYAimeNjaN9c3slpHcXNtaXYOuBkKzWxtSDKSv3UyloD83ZBmeOUDr1PGjHdv49RNXbxelGJ@LY@8UU4V6Dt8HTLYgjoyfj/N82kG/YhfkzBoeb1k1GGA0WZ3FDg720gcHsryLL7hUsJeW5Qa@ZDfT6Y1dWbYoZA@6w4wsuzwOBAGYz1/S6d09WR5wBGgCSJbb@FJax8GGLNv4srdzcIDpvMGXDMYHsAsewl86wcsGgDn4srpKoxVZfhuiA7gdntAa5bSEL5gmhhzwkD0Ik@XPg/yk04DhhMNxDE@Csu7syPIhf9nZwZAvqOBZntUv8WWHLlnuwwswoSy3wNHqW5YjyzVwIivKch1c9ZEJfviBFDQL4/imLI84gZBEsjwkaLN@IYNOLfwxmSdPnphtv2G1@DXq82cdsgYh9nBQOqh9/nmt1ar1Rzulz08w5IsvnphvRoN@rVUT0WpVuFyIAyEX3dH0BXk8rFbNzsyQLyHEmQqpjqoW5q1qvoU8iauFiXSrX0DIFxAyYz5zyLHB1QXQGl67XXjumjUKCS4KoeewVpPzyKj@qGfh7CO2mQsHZEGya9b7bh7fh4UlFlfiyVF5PV3Jkz/rKky9TudvMLyp0Ec4UR9F9Uy9HpWHhXQFRlsbGXEQR5HPh5msLSeXuo@MrWxuyXxkZNYSwxxaeXabcRbXjEeK8XDlnfJcfZRZXcvJ548eaXLZqDzKGJu59Y1XKwNZVnN4f7S6kXsHSmscNFO8qeWNyqONbCTKxkbCTGVyGxtq/gYI4kPXUxv4VrWqKFeWeaGqmGHs0BX1mkrLRlRSO99UhslhgeeKjZiaHxaMPDdQwNJTyJiiNNBEzgA/eKcyQtpigHL4KJ1DyazIxtamDHlIpRRVRcGEogSer18Gq1ThI@KYcPJLZzmNfy/T2FxXdTzXUXWbVfpmGHsdhUTNW3qJh7DoAHawV5IGS15OOkNFHfsCk6EqVMNP9NKhfRiycsNOjM/eGBtbklQUeuox/1pRXrx@/mRPB9VVvKG5Hf0Av8zu9nX8orA/EcJNwQReZ9C36U8s3AFZD/z2@NFovTSEcQke/8hfay@1m2iMU1DHeRp4OiRPtgbwnDXaHbIbzCwUwWU2FEqemeoVFbNaLBaqha7V7fkjGKjxZW4oVBD7@aDLdhmHxTNbwYmVamEXyp/OO2h6z8LX5WFsKBUbaFhot7B7PcihSniTtwr02Xk5hufcHjmFgeOZTevY6uMRq8Mj6LAtPMtUb78@LyHgHtD6@kYr9pkzLsOhx0kUHpihDF1jhkRAtZC@yUdzrZhasabmW4Uygr7H27YmyxVNK7@vwLArLxWhBeZHMbPgDWr824zpGoy41vND8DM21vJtVivUXg3z/UIPxggs3wEiRsY@zMwT/PsOdKlVvVoYjqmxWihnYPSTTgbjoQzun0tm0lvJjAF9KvS1EBN@G/C@Bj8DfhBu4GhJ6SgwupGT6WFaN5KGZSSV9Gu78VpN@m7JgQpJ53JYL1Cl9ApPU01kVjpKw2XmtkY1DG08T9k2k23Ws5NtBWKdWGaHg6saU7S3j9YT2TQ0y/xbyHN/WWnou@qjtXxD2WVVFTxAR4Bfhq2v5Zu4P@CVOkljkGR5ZUkteNZboijKCyJHbwkqRIwJvUG3nGZL60byWqtqNx3T85eNjUyuPFguawaUN/2@tS1/tyhXoHJuYFwusejyEqghefAL5AJXXMaqx9ivh5plx4J6NLYyeQEi9YSkUmQFv9zNN@wq8fhGJh5X43mcClkCfyHpSCTFQUbGHxqPZFB95Jy8lYHwsXy7lQM@vFqHQeCN1LC9HoOBVuxaurm@2Y7uKvqSjUZmQgteHzLWSixLLEXr/no1xpbIpelFmrDaKey0TnbyAnpnT4rlaMPbeEsSOxcHnJmWWvrU3QaJ7eIr/jzHnTWQrETGpsqsIoaLmVUodCPyDgX0riVOVb7jJLWdKLLUuSTL1Lz5iuVmVuV5ZR9i9OEGtnfdFGIp9wxHiEwxc7zZlivqh@d253pzVeOjTIXFPrBESqdNU9XUhxj0DDdE62CH3JevM1mgvuMGHjCe9EH@QUeSzco4NWO9Zr3TrVcbrzZfPXtx9OLogD1O5zZzm1Nzs@ePk0kjbsS32WNQZ@2TEgxO3jM3a3xwvuDbCGP5WK4XX12Lr05HLcSGhbVgSVoxikXN2M6wR8CrLAcyqmmsa@n3Rc54RQpYz0DIx1/72dpwexPeM6A25oCm2USmWDRWMmqs9/Hbf4sH4a5LX@08ZXE0S/C3f/Z7mY2//bN/Rauf8Zs8@mVWN2IAiU5jfSN2fd27vr6Bi4dlY5UYz9PahgpuvjZvxIop4W1sGGrM0/gbZDcb894LOyVKJr0JYXtH/E1eB2rGtmJSbPPZ6/eMbcPIsdhotewMuVKpW5PdyzkYncE/@4CTWx@0pdeF4nIKGABn6rYwQjAZs1IsFldwFp3Fiwk81JnJ0mR@@SZfYXy2BAcqKw79Wd4K/uH7K@6x4nnwHgTDK06kblssWzQYDG5SqY@/9luZzPrf/tlvnqvvq@@r3wHZu7W1tW5kYr@EfCw4aRWMTmgmA89MoSMc1bA5H43T67IUwy8JNhmHD8Y4OKrBc8bcSgu@SZfYGROJq0BHE1RKhcBW8LxIkpRLOlyq5iUpVMFIeey36knCwVbQQie0HelaeoBB0CmxAsgm6cEYFXh00bxLvep1Bv0e6UEKxTMqSfYQokAKD9AgwBKdcxECTjPyLLVyOyrPMrcNQh0661qehzaBQP5KDyDKU@BS@tQH65l4Vgoh@efDEYTySQGNMqRdgbQ7PEKVfBUqPQdIMp47HskB7VJ6gAc/SP2EPpvZ2wCQZ6r0AAgAZVAEYrvCttmqyq7tRCI/NiF0g7uX8Py4GZzEkDAaYmvg8aMgch7hbG4mYNBH0zlM1HDdinoGSDgOPsdeAMUYo9MbKiR02OreqAAXHbpVqGjs4cNxrgoFu6EyKhHiRwtKaPZobO/lVgKALBhSfNbIyUnmJBJY2Q8m2Q4onqDsAtdp5BgDNfFIDL7eSBL835tpkSOnqooC8lgAUV@8VdSBZBAZyc7rsI42oIzMhsrCzNch73XKFJmSCMdJ58PPdLLoUudZvJF@GQtM3En4Sd6IVi/4dvooDgO5NMCPnuA5Yy4MxCEbbg4fhdOhH8QOY0FR7A5BN@0@qNG0XhAYpVBWDRWjNUMfygftWsqsMdxQlFXxQbEQGk0XmGgGQKSzREctyX6S13MdshtAZzBx2xVZc/IkbiWBZ3vgXJlkAYinQruUIjniZpWQ88nqj8NNG3k8Lq5N1Pow1Atok2RWSycDGZktpnBTXXhA2wnRqRSJMgyjIhNpXOtYXcjSqWUxPLvu5VKplu23BzU6rP7MBr5qH9jQbTheSnxeJXVlX9ipM7SMqLlN0FbF4agY@8rs2KHdGHEinMw@dWz8HjpWqzJxus1jmfUkqHtJoOz4B4TN4UwjnmBLQ3CSQ8FvAx4b3LmZjMRdUkbq7eeqsaRUVVILyKRHHz@hcmk6EfrS9V4S4zBv5AVHV@ksFbzrociFlsnPr8TxAEt4sEoSZ2wLdP5TxyngngLqVHDiCp2gYlqXAKEZEvYxIDTrwVEwbMVQ2gfUAVDbg5aFth38fg7PSBbQ6pFSh6YnBLzDPmOrGfowNT81LA75Ag6s@sIkdgiDqFgOz29Axeh8hA1yBVpntwFhMTR1wtkP4wfcjW6yczJmb7Yk0GGnQ2kVGG8WwUs28oKtg1utgqIvQeA65HBGTpYUOQFoE7Iqc9Rh/OnonNslkiU5dhtTkiEGQWrAgqrCrulxa33CMMPV1ZVOtkEGfVu3PDSj6OGnoVK9lg3aqJvyYSQtLODb@PkS8WmmsUvjZlTxS2KPhvQBr62HI/6UpCaeVnw7sPuWEm96cewDL0FW9lpdOniNR6I94psDm8yK1hVawvIEm2UqyeuAzXLIZtpm/AaRMIZohslRsp4EZMla/SLZvGrkRcAltTtADpVlBZ5otqsfvHS9wGX3miGE69MGyOC91rmoux0XVQ@ZTySOk@YlDCBHwat479lDiORYV2yn3zdHCoWrCI18qoxIu2Ej6N0pBJzQm7Brbt3GHpZHlYnowzA69F3B2IP18di1dL0YKTcqhOFDHj6E8CEPH44TDZItDytc80KvGywOMjdaUQkgEc0ogLnhNpHGIYQZ9GJmcBQIOZrwu4FfvUCxA3rzN6jHQsAYwBNkikxBG2jl84rjWVcrlUSqBTwtEyGgxgF1uUI0vWqEbqR@57LTc70JLweNjEDnI/KNXvW24AbOK1jGsIKIMTi9bLRF0erqfKKE9/uiwIAB1S0IRA1gx1dsNR9agaRAYJyyPKYxz1hZZKZCSpYIEn6gFXHSc8JGEVUiiNA/LBJkE0JY0HKEkVwhBF728XuCAaxGVtzJnGW8EgdKTjUVLlLyVEmRXGlakE0gO2qlhemiBOFQFeWpoEgxb0T9R7O/9MnZb0K7mJ17YljeL@SlaFOxhmi6zxLNhajKioVIvUIOUitmx@pDB1XiaqjolCGZlVQwmuDpYBG4yUklUvl1ldcP7S2XHTkXssKoUIAijgq8WfJ2EZCUEzyM5oloo4ARRHwuQABHemY0S0QbRqMNCwUuONhwTrSrSCaHlMkhj8Khh3MyWRHRYJAUGjXE6qmgLStQqGTAZ/DeEu02yswzL9E4J3uDtidg8BSkOZY5xAWCh1CTRj6rV2amXo5kOiK0phAgI95C0OA2@XPStMAztPAtlFGclIGM4m@CDbisAAYjEZzn9oWUkMloqAt6vZygfgDarpwoS7KBW0joL81/cjLwDH7Gbc/0JKQx6ZlOTv39g3hWkLKRBhpRMoz0GgpkHLDskLkFUEuuXKbMUJ7BPxV8dDFV67i1VNfE3QL4ddbwU4xqMB4gg2qPe65v@u7aWo4PgmzirxcCnEXsYfMxgN1yXBhqRO2X2dzemhNHs3J1t@XYnpXEjz9yFdyi1W5uvliK6r3C6XqSJGb9@LAUUXMGQtW1WsUPh1Srimd1mmouNA6IrzryYTwu4XgWXJH4IIcE0qOe4uKXb331bpxo3E9EO7PrF8pRTwTGIZEdBsKqDvo8hLZBVWGeOx4JktUtVI1rvkLGm9tu122BeocW9TD2FPrDMW7MkNnrUV6SzMQhai5iApGag1JPmqqI@uUnR2VfZhRTDeNnJhFMECPJ@tM0Rsr2ZyRXnZscjxakd/rp@T2N5vd0cX5pVD2dZz7ULvDAT0t6VRljAMBxNlbvzkZSGLC9lZ2JrITeqEDxCPfOYoN24zQwpzsAuiPA9SbwRzJ888ishsj4V/Pov7gCg@il@1afid9ROh2BvOnipi@FzJd7weKPAuCHKsqe28mFrL1/z7QAFvQIdoC6AuirJLgctNkCDbMHw2hPDpc8BOI7eB634dzie9qbU@CBM/LUv0yyi8z8KtqvNqyOObIaioBMRvAGJT6BkRnJq/sVHAUdCT2XD@oU6KTUqMFXJDoHys1hGTN5GTH3ewuGg9gh99DMN@XwcD79MPyWaMYpuwKffQaFPx6PkWVoMuTdG/VG3NZdhxv5F3KU9z@8JvGE3d0EATqIFfzkOFl1kfg8UcIi3aNHCGH1ySKTVZug23K7vdt1@GkkurukULmRSIWglies8c6rcXtRjUe4IuBJvp5zP5a8i@nuzXMRVuPIxiJs79O6kFuYcYdAva5EMXKfhTXmOrdkAvrRvJszp1epzhCoYUySdL5N42rSL1QJh8CH8MQJpK/giQhbll/lDBWUDeeoxOcgGIV0zV5EaxE@oI0DlggVA5vrlI0IlBS4Afz6JkyzPjfN@q006xNphi1gMskIkFSfSFLUAlbPoiroWE1/jnTGIBwkw2OR2IbLcc0@Tktcx@14zk6y@GU8BwI5bsVzJQWEcrwRz@2Tw4vnTslxEc99CY5x24q/j@eCZoEAfXglx2P0FyIc3@vx3J6i3kg@msUP0tXjubBOAeYRfyWKACmw3KA14pKZ44pi@n0LOjZSKpMMOcZL4jiJJlyS9EvDP7d/zb/TAIE4Z7lCwCzBjIlOI9Jj8HSg2wgsI85oyTnRm5eODmiHzdjAOIQnYDAXjUPoQQ2PxSeFEc8YhtIKBTwhgyg3c7NzxIxJK/T3yI5IHTiUKnkyfaKeTvpAQ6HwMgBX1Enj5iJ@UF@TKHgF3i@fGHlePm9lJ0iOcoRrrOqMbCFRX8cXFArrespyP6/9aA3R3PUkEH53LADhtURoIzIddDhabMPEem5vkkkoFHe12dE4NPvGGyVy71Q0kgqiZc4JJm9RMhQM0cavLipOJB5mbUIEYWA5XeGtLOwXSBZj0FjWRTRV3vggCxGZAy3cql9YyLb7wklwXNwkqa@Y1w0FcXmSJLkmxSRE1tFUwMD0eerh4LWEBgQ@bfgaxBzipIqCCCIxw1S4fHU/QX93uf4eKNQBEaYSmKVYz@5Kb6vXC3vZqZx3xsnerkAMTLJ9daZyFKYwJjmMDiKa@SJeu6Xi4xYOruTzREPsU9p@QLZwTHAH3abHFhwXagn9y0nPiwx4XmTmE@q2RtK51AOlRceUBB5e8DCn46Itzisv@KwqxhCayDY7n1zB/ckKjlYe4qMC9KdIzls5HvrCta1x2yazk@iDItXIMS7IafkzrOaxJ4h7WooNl2HB46h6sn/0/Ok30OlubGyooo8ejfOHrRYnVcN@nGOmvbdhfzBj2JJJotllXLymT4vjd/yWzh35lizhwhqUAfzcRMB@oo2rQpZF5PlU24V4HDZCUYHrYtwMzAmphKqOiV22LejqA0EsX1kxBZJAvQV6J2m0puKcLHAHfrmqWqXuq1rFzUjVqujFsGqCFW71l7Gl1MDr0wfUuFHYK0miI5ps/4i9fLJzxs6elNjBi70v2TdHL9jLnedneMTx@MXu08M9Br/S89MSG88o4IWG8nFACXTdt@pWtwYiO5NOrzHCvOf2RlzuKHsq9z81u@yJW7dwPWrbM7uP2/xFdyy/yGOVYDg6Et8Chox2bd/nH5mqAzpSbhp0Dgv3rzOArcGYtotj3q7bsJs2wEo49u3ZlhccIGIdG2oQ5G1wrC7JlSQ02k9bgeiDTfStLfxYE8DjIg2gMb3xx8Fsj0ewGjoThAuvT6bgWenk2Snbeb7P9o6e7x@eHR49P2UHRyfwevzN4fPPgZ6Hp2cnh7svMIgAnx3tHx4c7u2QB89AWmd4iJW@vrUoCzqCE1XqF7jETR9EDN@is84ABho8uzLpRJrH4gMHpY9tdux3ViOel/BzHvwUHK0JsPBjWsx6i0uZwZov7SeQX3j0QYrlNNum1KCxFKG95UVzhW4PTQPjwkN3xPDDJFaezpYq5B5/8IQ25TRsi8l7uOcE5775EVRqywFqSGgJcCOqYANKgZGd7Xg8uU0oi5BaveOisSSeGt8UKF4w6uNg60heIoqJvS@IFLfOHzo4H2TkQw/ge/DIiGT9Pgdgq6EHB2Br3ANV0UPcC8KyAmLgHw1QPLN17vGm2zug9V@2EXrsmjSK3RR54vVGVWqy8YdW8evxZCmdz/LQB1BMr27bFMUjeLQ03ukEXyGrWcDyIBPFN2NwrxpAyiBsmrjUILaxOQNq2BA6wI@Ke22z6XtMKag6O8PNPpZjcxP0rY7p8C1N4604xHtsEw0MFMRuazu07d7gXzkmBsTvLUzmI4y3L7RC677xIOburRRNseeRvg8SbCm7KwO7tzLwq6ABRNrESKdOPRUdVUQ0blOwsuK5wJE4b/shCg/s3BjUrYkIwTfi3tjv3qmCyMmJcVKw75ByB1WEn9NL8jXLptuHNk5itYtnO1AK1ttuz7d5HSqTJRh/4adLH6zHDL4uFCdSo6/6TaXouE4k0Rpw8ZxUa8CU90mVOJ4vkofiK2jr4SeGaB8dZsesuZdWZO0siYtIVxZOv4AizD@Phr0Nfe5S6J/SWHZ8oE/WbRaK@7vn2ofXSTSQzsUC/yhQsImQf@Kui2lB86B1PtqA2Ee9S7S0wMq@N6hhbLGnTkhLbOUBMhgHtm0Y1z2u5sMwvn34tj@eLZn2J8/37ws8loaSiUvkgddWxtItycpBkkmKU2Fir0dEdkJmQdYrgU@ScIby@jEeFMFayANFHJQj9HHKSev2QoQEpasNmiBZxPdrRHWH@FVWpK0TgSJJlxKtj9QrZbeQKKqp8c4RFiGnEojoZIAZP28z3n9C/dUtdPuL0YH8vj@6zYW5493DJ2HbX4jtk/KmJebj4t1SBNf90X5YgJZ3br8SWih7cj5i3knexhZyesicyeVYuDt2cYqvb9UdtT1Ag30vzqCESCOpDRxaog4sGio8ghpFM1aITs/2SycnTObjE4gLcg@HDA0hBhH3Ejf@z3fP2g4JOz1UmsLBcqg8BT4TW9fCIx8LGvNM4s0RFUIHSQp6hMJi8lN7JPVEz0IqBO2mJ4EYUG4yd9eBDPLKAvENmrAE4RUbq2FhAaWZxYzxzsf2opu6Bd2SXDeO7smnHdO878aP5vRHUUTRzT9mC0@KzK6/l1w/zgXpcAXLejugAjdAk8bvRursFBLuAaCuT9bggmoJqhQ3zXMFOxbQDnd4pSc17L87QxEjcSWc68IRsS6UY5E1rh8vB2oO7TzEbsDELZ0ikO9QhoBAxJPPdrRC1XGnp0x2QaBk4udcHke5AqJXbvLhFyCVcT9ZCBXyaFtbptyUg1xWcHZW4M7PB/oM9zavT4uH6aRA2i5MSvv7SYr3EhMpBTSfWZggEDCvZ7Ord@GeLkUQXfu74uZ9yLT89Ls9GN@PUXojj6b3gXMPnyeD8DEDLCAd3yofNJipiKDqzOhTJspOnVE0f5AXPi8EmUETofU2frxmMlWVDafyNhs775Gi2AnkVhkiTTgsKG81t6h/szg5FMh3prf06enxxoZAuEfw5pfh4bqIzZCIFx4TnfSz@n2HwPixpK6Lx8foNNLCM3N0aI5vaOWFwUBaZosWoCkOGfFttclgioESoVlFHT92hZN6@elZPc3IR0t4cPi0xFbIclVzYgpS7stqROQs2c6iDJDopekI7DXoKN5nXg5@kIdkgBLIRIfyFKKNemfeiCKgLJfJ@rrY9ilEqjFd6U2vbjpowCIp03diH0JEmnwtHR2osybU0/mJ@JA5r@coECspa7pMUcEP53ER0yQKXpvoH@mnJLQ@LjZILvg0ppkyNtPrWxKVzkn6yW55q5JcqRdkBn2u6XS9Qf@qcdFy25dN1mG9N7VhffTuLWPZNYZHfDMPuY0@Y72Ap1sVhl/z2WRbaWJYkcFHZG/wXGaMLHngWe04Gw@/80toPg4uGivn8ATEFJeylW7AhXhSzi90y@uVglNI57tlp5LHs3p@ouAnjISCHg@h8wTRwhfky34Fu9JfRmdbLeeS9Qe1EYySwrMfjM5@YP@OM1xizzbNl9M2Y@kBblbDMyS6Y10p4Wd/kTMl1H@kB3SIx8DT3jRdjLMtDRtyANRPgrLqDek@UqUHaX3Q810KEQlpyELsvf1eehCcOkrThAGAlO1KkJ1twjOGUXDdh/uO@G5ozeDamIFHHdUIijLGJGknn8syHgHEjIqjV@WK5OmWWW9jJvADb@8pGtve5l9@voFgmqTDnRpmnw4@pCvoxPUNePRoMQGTIMXco@MbEhQf3w10cB@agvLpvAttdJdIEcQQ3MbNruk4EsXfBgJwwj/gKpUuZjCFYgV6Ij/qR3MHaCFtclyPqwh4CpJXygMsLOLm6RXGyGnHN9EIkxVkAv8HV0hOTiu4RAk0g95uFSOEVzk4kYSWocWbh7SkKqWgIj4642hKJJoWRAuAI6R4cCc1cCILRj/PLGg@I7ZndTqQaU6LB2NyoJOO44r0E2H6XhnTrISZ5@HarXBtIlzn4TxTYygd@u8xUC4KJMeux3A3TB6DJW@lVWCkm@hQ03UdNI4xbH4RrKf7btUeAxfDquRcGQZsTwRokZBXM2qfhyxNxAkZPAwv83DB3xlR82EuJ2AfT6aPT0lUkEV7Y8VWkiku1R2784h3TmEIspnM8FPiPDrWN7Edb5TiyKQQJ6Cg4TQ@NdtiYYwlYQQSh9qMXNx@LOtCmXikTGeDHzq81bBmtJEIlSjNBBFuSOcLIR0KXoqgIJzIaCxoucUg8khEHkXQItRSkCw/tHirgUPRppt4AY8xvsdb0NgnMxfAxWYHPuA5H/LC88PIkwQiobskzybTpDTBYx/cUxRqQS8yTns0jXG2kHgemeQN07T4kekmznIvhXIiKigCSXGL7mGIoPQYwAjYd14VYuCN9MvUivS5CSp0r2MN2Q6OIkw6TSVNnEf3Lc/30H4RGmmE4Xmv18FFRVLsrujEs7DNkcniasoYY2QZTZcOceMOh0@iS5wfh0g6O0LMV7j/YxzgDVot/t1whpaLQLTihIrt69KOM@LzFdBmVjP8VLjFBh5fFIXBfCuaCV5zvPWEH7XXJdDFPNByJF7UJm/fYrocj4WgRSro0nKS9J2BXb/Y@xyXazeM9KoRIdmlWO1N66tr44NSQKQgIJMGdTVrrElSZOm3zpd@NUSYZE@xo/8KeNO6xI@bSjvQYxCgB8qpZ/UvrYYuSSdWuMaLeJGVceERj027g36dz92AboUfRcXTvl6Sr3YBh@ET@2e@GlynpbCkhGtS48Vk@hB8AwkYHChpurj4S@sReKqf0wMjdS0fiLKissks0dKyyAvpLl2cZwJqmOL75mLpISSD4/p2HWqGJqqkDqDiqxzjxPgnnCM5gfTqHRMP@eqzMoCnX8YUCDIQrBQtyoMk1sQ/KQ/Bh9uDJXQzqJkUSD@X2go0d6tvg/QdE5hqhaJF8g4VfPbk8JSdHh2cvdw5KTFwH58cfXW4X9pnu9/QEjaug5MVU/bk6ClIl3CxnC@KH4GHvHMKMWUKkHaef8NKXx@flE5P2dEJO3x2/PQQsAH6k53nZ4el0yQ7fL739MU@La4DBvb86Iw9PXx2eAZgZ0dJSjWIJo3jsaMD9qx0svcEXnd2D58enn1DKR4cnj3HxHDRfocd75ycHe69eLpzwo5fnBwfnZYYFkzaPzzde7pz@Ky0r0P6kCYrfVV6fsZOn@w8fTpV0KOXz0snjPYAREq5W4Jc7uzCUBVTonLuH56U9s6wQGPXHhAPMvg0yU6PS3uH6Ch9XYLi7Jx8kxRIT0vfeQFAEMj2d57tfA6Fk5Q7qAL1svfipPQMMw2UOH2xe3p2ePbirMQ@PzraJ1qflk6@OtwrneaZ9PTolAj24rSUZPidGUoacAC1IBzcuy9OD4luh8/PoM94cYzbGVSo5JdAGMjlDkTdJwLjLgcsLRDp6OQbxIp0oApIspdPSuB/gjQlau0gFXDDxN5ZFAwSBCKeRYvJnpc@f3r4een5XgmDjxDNy8PTkgoVdniKAIe43@IbYB1I9AWVGusJ8sWdwKxSwLlJqk52eMB29r86xJwLaOCA00PBLUS2vSeC5tCWU1JkssR2cW7A7EYnUJq3vS4tNE14e@Zl9lxMaOBo72i/BBoft58lj/1fQKezOWX4KBoGHU0YCK8TBmYaVm3QqtpO08WjomE0Pr/R9VpJtLuvwuicnUsLPr0gplEoQixWrX61U4Vx7mm1qibvE3MiG3fFEJPci6BUUcaOy4034PxOLsfJvj1BqOJDsYxJ2/BweQEhOfEf8o1tZtdSWSrVsEQ0PIOPiIMZIo8virRxoQQkIx1lREv04yRpAoLebcENFFEJ0Ov1Ks6C4r5HAnI9uDnvxy@8b4h4gHDms1qpFI5hKRv2OytIhidClg3oJgwL2E1KUvcs66KlpKPJ4ZBfb7luQ1HVIA7B@jAMbCnqHdFrVmsqujYdnzJLi8p18en3YNhNGky4uixIxkS96H0qmYK3qk8PNcgNN92Ac6KUFE1Fi7lJ5SGPjvuNkkxYqMDDE1TJqPI92/n68CUO5tKZtfyU/5PQn7ct3A2IVlWhvytTvAo9nlQ4ADQwMqkBJLGFoYtUKhIn2E0SAl8BYBuBruwG7uuBrrptUbcOJAE9dmB2omliZ9y3h9Hcgxj@/GTn2e6LgwOQnJjbtc3sxnpeCo1kfZ3kz28wHbIoSjbCetCNg5pGQZFWsgd6D7WUiIHoMfsTA6dSCIgmuINKI0801xDuypjcp4RyDIvr4WcZHNyAJ1tIB5mRHY0lKeDXmS1TMIAyUVQVS9M1h6Thm6AqEQ@IrSqdEdXa8P9r79m22zaSfDa/AgZtkaB4190UFEu@bJzNZTb2JJOVFAokQYoJRSIAaJFWtOfsPuwP7Afsp@zDfsp8yG7dutEAQUuJM0lmTnJOLBDoS3V1dXVVd13wH2xbL3@1xPWAhICExCgeK1AuKBfE9@yXyhCUdBsKs4NF6raiYw66pnFAJ11kHYu@s/RLaNuYxYgNFXG90rRTTQDiYRYKS1lNTHll/4nChcg5L8X6gjd/EXqDx28kHB0Fp/Oi@Dh@DWh8qWvicXRy5iyDPpWWz49cmKKNDd3ToYWH@Y4ARWtPTo11fA9jNRAo52gy6FqZhjs6HEi2S7JvfVpyrBumVIzBge10hGLlN1Bu3nCklY4KAyK/VXAJi9vSsUoYa9e6j4Iq8o0OR6HQmULTB@GD2v8NcZLT/iEonNB6gi0jZN@9MEmtMq5AeyWkjK/VfYJxiZFg03z1TdLMrTkxl3pgckmzYO8ZQIHMzlK9@IaCFA7LOQhAIsdzDXP9aoOzSw80p6e2I9XxOmTavwrKluwVaqtYafe8SjJXVV2g4A/HcvigyejuU6hoPWUbuVgULuBivaX1OLK5jc2Wo2J3NCp06KFXOZHmJRuiZsmpKUtLLX4Jk2TsMgMd7QhE0du1N3IVy4himWL4cqvldMzoluaABW3Q5xECmjtutMBnU9x0tESOB/6GIthhJGrUmXErknBzPTK6nPjYzuMBnYxgxsj4GreLCbdOYfaS1qzyYzIKwU4SC8MkRiAyX6cOWKdN9lpDT8eUSK8a@j9POdK6z0dcqkSdg3kIhKZrfN36zFsizJP7jdtOOt9EtB6l@381pdCD/Zh3ymAWkeYOvaCm/zhKMKLMcGAfSrAk9pe2otHxdW28gD/UV01GroI4gs5AASbzhP7btQoBxZdM35Ba9tlUHyI94Y3MfazEF3zitaufvsEnOWd2YVAAHLzB61QRgxBklJvwCm91tRF8GBvu67EfDsxjOdhNB16AJ0Akfs@mtO2q0yuJINf34shfghTab4wXDWqjW/5kdjntPptNvNF4NvZAV8AY2gtegPi4pEeM/zkKZ9cRZSKhDwOj0GCZPHMEE47ohb/11VjHiPIUxX5QNm/E43B5fMmBCOjwFs3MLM0zKYhqkA23pets7ySVCmkPR7L4ajmdtXW3WnmV@fIYG5BldZS5rGcvxZhcXwz3xs5Kgd77Chgw9qya5TlrbMJSEB8AiugmIAWxAmblBtwcBGoHayE@HSyqAwpnF2IoH/@5j7k8ojK9rnqY5g84/Ud4Kf3Eau03jap8kL/AkHb4sFyP7vbebww9APAB4Le28qgljxAooO9QxfOJWGaWuJQACxmgoVllFTUBUJJn4XgEiu0k1Wh3kW01/Xm5DhtkZAJbs0RsW6FKXJFlEL4xVVW5Cyynu3SsH3@0SlbJocgQuCMex@XmeoL177LQpMWP94h8eIOM6Zm0XDaAXoeqPmAJc7xlDDhNkDkK790rpt2@76xlEOjmGTUZGQLKttovycdBZB68WZmFwIztDPbE2qAUxbOgdE/sreUduUG@8nDdd5w7TU2Z2NzFZrsyINS6S3xcdgpZeDJEk8YYGTUBDaEKRc@azLNIXLhdXG9ud3kHHtbhLDHR0ZuKnu8Br33cFN@izajaaPSSItgx3mVHvz/twsC76zmItMkifpc4RhdZRnfJj0ZTGTRpLN0fQ0R9AnsGHwPAHPY7ANyZ87MWqVl7LBU9U31KxUtEfGKob3QLBL4UDPH@HwOR8RWJZlIc1dx/goFd6TapVethvFr8wA2is4pfS85C@BQxmawMHVE8@WG5iwYrLeRE8HRkXrLrMPEaYRTHXQ4Y5NK9u6y1zjvc0kK3BLIslXpfS8qjGX6edhfUygoqYInnoEKPaIU3Xd5/VB86FigHLXBt@iy2pM0qDsaxNgEa@Mf81F2gDJx0JTVTKyq9ELrEGmAtgBoymvisPaH0Nw6Z4vGCXZYRiPb8uox/NqUGBoDebWpsY5XFYIlFHEE3rzbHqh1xlYSg@DeiX5Yii7qkLkEDPkMM9d0WtIARMgl6PJim4C4m5aUAlTmCim4LlyW8pACbiUlhzndEqhTY3jFKNPNKHJht1HIbAcEiv0wCCMgs@UWSVmCjy4XFKLGXP56kBAjEivYZ4zAVMitpHOqZYwTCI0GrOcppy6o2hYLp4/aOk/qo6Zu@HjSNr83sV8CPhvC01sp@3W@mvqa6bbfTVVM1AR@O2WvqI6DCMQHWXOHD/iPnBzN6tjZLNJSMlJQhpsBTVKWuUW@rfxdZh@T2q2QM1Z7pe6zUry4n5UjF935/LG9LIsV3PnywyjZSASLB5SnwmfKmKLM@SAKrjTs9jgoVXRXKTXvAK5V2NrS@evPyZSquaG@pTF2u/HCn2WwiDffMMOrKihfPL8azRrp0YzifTBrB9SfhV70GsX5MnzyJZk@UAu3DjMCaiOqzcMSpBBAGKIqla@Ipiar@fDg0Y/bjJRnOHcwalxR3e4v2n7E2u/jqDR3wUJOyv17gAHF8F5ZefNcey5nSiroJgdpolPrWVhc4gB58MURLYH1ZQo0hX1b2NLBtOe7RDW4gmAqDJosC4To3iYGs/bE/mcyq1tezcDJAV/QHt9kKL1@aFZpcBC@5yH10HlHA06rlvx1PDMdVLGKSOjan9iWVmEBFGMco61/6oxeLoGyffmvDrgJD3sRhbmKk46plj2xHwo7fo1mmQwD7XqWvvKDcJzxlC8NOLws4eQKItlrVXNUnVcShFCOCs7tLI1Lzwa1TNAAYukOigIqKTtNLI1lTXCPXPlu0hojDJrchMGFQj/vVQF@m344rvo2Hw/sxRQoozxP7qzNEOpGmFSjLD/CJ8Zj/uQbL@mUmYgXLN5j2YZXvYIUuVigUHvfdH67Lx8fH1qNgc9M6Pj6Bh1rNOj45tp7ji5MT6zn8PsHfG257Z6fDPPe5cwMvT9TLW@sE2qADzs3@ZfgcfsI3Fx2T0F4Yp/hRw31U7TzquodHnahxenyCfuPw9Nd//8@//sd/NY7lx3/jjxP6cfqtLlSv1xuP@jePNm47@Pv0@XnpUe/0UXBeGnWQypDd/zmMvIlnGDDW@4U7nHQGk3FvneOOtuAYR2QtiBZ7ZfjHdUED@/FHfjqLk8cwecSwnEl1bxJcelTdohaO3NJxaWMDng7d0r@W6OxE3nv6/Tt4bznIy8lvn1CLqWes49fPXr0yI18j1yfpfehjmBZMnSjXJuNpNIZBXRRVzrnaqVWvW@c160KDh6YGXS6YBpHVTAbm3wRINTqyC6H7U1Eb8GKUjr75RJ7vSa6iEcl36uic8295oqk8HjzhSx1qYxMYHpbvsLm0uF7i8AFcvIVxa6et3Z3zWrFYLOicXN0@sTnqLaC@dI4mdY1LdzDsCRTAkoGxc7Z3xAU0iMgoFilj00afM4uVp6hak8bECnexZMjzeN5EAyloNscn3OzPjzIWKnyUBcuK5uQIgLLB8r5XSgAAeXgdEuOyONlsFPj98XCpr90xKULSO@yV6LVVsYYrTluWHfZsGdfDYdIgIASlAAoXg41mG2TkzaDsmLgdj1H9BnFjlaguJP60tU0TrI1SgtlkOZpAZ2Uy54mugTsB5h2ZrMlUeXNhD1yz5w8x1zmvaJ6wxJwU4e75eBQx7YOCOcAURRMMC8UCH19BUkBEWA8o4UiKsiF6I5QnUzZimQ3hETZ8dOTidGxEhpu4pQpBoVKLyrFKcSZ8oBI4jhVwScQq/E4ugIk86AiS9GHJtZa6CgwcqYlvD4XSAswuh4q0hKd0ZCXZtFb0BSxIlVd4QYaXY4AULFmndFbAGpbWxWR6ocfPV2oRZsSj@zNOOEfdtPmOHDiW7kZ5bFN3bI5u8@EqJb@aerGgN5hF0bgHyIqXapooCh/br4fQ6lmpwJ0JteBFHSIYX1UCvaLM8SlS8hcBuYgzvA/waHeqqCBVEK8V8U6M74aLqZvi6WxaI5bb8@Nxn434uPeHihcHeE1L1vsE2PqOQHngi0o1wdTDmQpwI3eUNNVJO4QntJfH9X@pRW@PcCbHvMKixXcBANLEoWfnLEFS0qKmBGogjRSBkUyQBYMPUoQ58UfjOFWnKkEA2PKZR3GrUI@L/AIBNrGbwSza6tOq7Bn7zIXgW5kHIONV34DR7jvif5tHe2owuKtx7kNdk4dELl37q/Sh@ZECx4QaVjCgD5dvNT1DtLniXkdxzDCa5CBNqlYyC@/tgRoXEJlfVMjHhBoQbpHFSe0UsNHOYAPYaWYZJFy4mWreIGAkbnMnJx6VQS9PF4sEK8xb0YuCFIngtqC9Sm7@1v2mprIXoossLD4ohXQAe3Ri5qBDOWSbzF2B174S1CU@G7DGcI5B0dh8QnYUjKIy5kVqdKrhyHSlhi4zXCNJKaAQHfDztGTOZaaqGm9S@zxdu1Zir6Ib5VtUNiSdwBGXI/n6QFLR7@6odtlpiK7e6Net8m4S5yBtM6FmR1BO26s3RPSgFQal@dGTc5tHGkqHV1xejVkkCxAuU41TW3RFI@VMS5QcJLGtwvE8nr2Kf3mZnsIby12ffkkZP0Eu8EAMFhHBcxryBI9oAev8UmoB8oExMAK2ofIiH54LBZY8RMO0P4tGJ7NFuVk9s8/samv3wLFJT9ZyWLEfgWZU7PscsAuzBoruSYEB6Vz7rc8sPOyNBwN/qsKBQlXpTX/qSrOneJx/o9ldxElWbWLivm3w8qgGk0gvBNf0HITe6Mqjx89nb0Jv@Qo2Ifr5xZTn8zW29yVsRpgWiL58yWv0eACihn2LenJCE/caIrkseSD59GMSDTgYnCEu5CDAX0EA96nHH6UHa6DBHD@fXWjpmfZNmNQLllAiNuS94IuTiwLnnL3CpKhdfge0WTaS0sojfcpkShYZAT8oGzPjLddgUX@CNz3@NHUPoaLXCuFx5mKuVbUmQKBNpXK9fygztsm90NBHF6LYxP3L7tV8Eo9lZCvDUuPCStn0u6ROqozJa1Lw0pFhFnfGOLDd0zGs0kSXIUaVYEGUMNWKoT8qdNP46dgxERpEVeHIE@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@ZDeJVzHDFAQs3FBI5KlZXnNju3v1or1tzLJ0aX@6RNHDk5FCa2XMlCNCY/K5T6kZRoimULWjecqyfeUBNZyVt3oPwnKdRLDwAEFjSwLBu0BnV3pQD3siHYeigkHycm5hhsX6oDrp/T@ffCsfKVkEoQAsITSUdoHxGWYh5gkVCIGdKWqClx1EJUK1dOXJ7SUQ1EhcJtSlKVjt4S7bq3AMhPSu0S0dWksQzjI1TxdxTU3VCZBVzq1lljHKJpxl0deT38SBcn1JFjnEeLMcODWhbkkIDWOysp5tMsStzOBsblsBGR9YZGSNX0U8hiuFIIeNsysw5S7rAhPAlIV62FFgmWuoLcs8fuICUSFbnRr4gguw1kUOSE5pGgvf5VGM@HztU9X34IWeIWcbJhXBCHFWHH0mgKfxUhGbxeQeR0oHe3w@V/qSZuC@pSurodbTIe/Fei/dic@9ZRg08bcDdB/@O@@xrSs6Nyf5jVUwH4Ae8/9IxBfzDBEr@CrF2ZAduH8WOpLt@kOh19SjucuZuzX5RjxOTu8EAtmNgtuTZVAU9MSYbJMvAszKwJSf3n7RhKiWduxdWCComgpLVzKR2opdZpJgZ6q/yjCdMDcWV@AE0R@ZF5E2IV1ezPvumwwaF34fkmU56bYvVIlSIuOIp/hQXvwdDjpQ3lJXMI7AqXelWxiDw0CBYxjoJvfheIlZyJccG@zp5fZYOo3rBevXTRbL7yGWVe8tlxQqdaVcS8axSDEC22PqZbfy6clpyQAvt2BpyGxcqHeCTygEohgmaoIVxcpgvXMu8cvv5Yt8f4svvdWOo/O7Fl4pGfz8txFQSIaafK8QkBaRWHw/eqJ4uT@wBlu2UNOSKiD3c3yzdH6wb1d8stz9OBm4l5aTyjLrF1zndxtczqaEJVTqk88fcjpDX8pq@sGVtX1jl1QXN851sw1t/bMP/2NtwQ@MCA17esdMYU//H3P8jzD2GUJzsN/eb3V/s3le/s03CsjP3rZZlP7RaRx/tnS2eN88WB9tf/FCMi0ftxtch/I2LPxR394v8CA/wa0v9els8Kh5isd3b4rLhui48SivHL6GVo090m1hqeQj/HO2odneXxaOaS9V/LB7twkOr3QZIzhYvDs4W@0383@78nsQP83ZFCx/rWg0oropsCHwXKCbypJbPoqTJZ8bu8ApJQKnj6QNS3Pmh0RoBjMYzi/Z@U2QVICCO//DWlxRQVz6m7tLHUxTDJKY4GuxxoeI/iK0eV4IVoLtw4A91Qbu9iF5JzAkVbgKlhARo6@JxfRevri8kDIUGQAeeIDGTTblBvShTxxhiC/8eNT@ydWCKJ7bErbBNi3@525RdcV92xf8rWsEyvpxN2zmB1YvWM5iu2Le@ixiWaDoOAj9miX/kT33YkvEwfTxDQQczvfUxL95k/D2b/z1RjVt9aqj7XdRl3xxuqB4sLfvRU1hZ4yvSit7BqlTPeD@2u61@AePGnGHoJ6O8a0bj@HLeo5j4b8Llq/gLikTRwLjaMUelaIAs12tceWg4QJHkIyAxKAHsIJxPG5RbDAQ29JXB8O9X3vcAGuYzhaENulAMD/u/L1Py0MgPyMVlMRzalKnHnwxe@4EXehw1Da3m597If4WBYWAyoksblaei9Tk518RmdFytLBHGQQ6XlEw1jmBFvD8qKfdPQq1lobsxZYyx0U9dmBDxbrtOXhNQy2bXAspSPZzN4qQ8e43rCvQzXYNigsEksWsIXg4mIwJujuPfVEBsWpa8IDiSn9Jp8oI6ImhCa4yZHHBU/nR@RbSjM6uetp6cS9w0t2VkuCaL1/0nktXcthGhOE1y2Nzaxy9ztr2ke8mChA7Q4wDBmiGBgjwhc7otvAJNIYpmve8o7g9yJViQSH919U2WPZnRwyMedk/9kUe84ro3jqnAYBxRAazZGL0D2Z1RVE2Ram8@iuq8FsixYhxFc39nb3@bAKIdXxUdzPqpou0GtBx64bJBwF3GVxM9ioP40pr4b/2JWK8Q2BRRlhcl0Rkm1fLmEzJr2XWIdACVqZECFsoHVX73/MXLT4/fvHheBTFlB4tH5Jaky5YN5PLnTfo@nGCkBiYjrMLLt97b3WYiL0fV0lM8kWPQn5po3zQBVg1EUR33gHFQLrlUTewsuGErQLV9Oqrq6/DrWfi9DlyMyw1BmVO2A1shV638YhFduiLsq4gkmApsAHVwYMpzO5wA41kptJZXAAaEu3VjoMgJ8k@kXPvwYa2m19QTeqoBY63VjviQxX42GYPiWfpyPk1x2xKtHc8qAZPD639mbQ9LxBfqdse6dFGP7/TdZkf77b0tz50bnRV5iFCUGXFvZidLNX/luXim2YAQh6yclcvk//5PyencJkF0JuXYwej/1jtXBS@uM1N/welSy6WoD5MVQ7V39dhfxM842qQbd3SF3mywlLT3z0CrHpTfmX0EZecG9urNzb7rbjk30GUYYBTKAJih/wZadDr4bph6p13EGmdnU8yBXEHXvb989unHMOVoJ@ZH8em355VHjWqp5DgdHILnkn/f8y8@@xOe8odOnU77X4azK8FL6OlO6jDbV9Fp85ygr9o4tAauQuCcIz@W0Ucnyzfe6HOQlsolD1CAZknkGAeTMj70xL@sg7ZJKHNhfhATR66dnlzbuRm5VOoy9IcdPqu4jdy35ZHTieHPpdnFDnThttvUegyVXLRqymB9PIXd@uM3n33qlg49C1t1c1ZFabOniQMIhQimjK@OMSNSinSAqxBVxeytRwQD/22W7KP0WA4b3lGpc3u7Fp5POaYrCD@lhIAH5XlVKC50V6e0EyZUsAx8F1/w1vZPL97YVaiLIVjw5RS3tyUxLXZidVUfTG7IKWgLXL7GMq67vbFB77DKPHLddrPpYESUW2gtwhTm0CwvrLBzG3ruoKwR6QXjnIQ97Xq7wY4sUaO1227u7H00C2GLcDEn@kYELMRFreXtOF5ugGzouyr5zwbIybCbug@3K/tfjE/@5S8Hr3efl/u9T1p21f4uIrP9MDABCL3rOotFwGNDifdKQKDnYt9rBN73s8b2oNkHybO1N/D3dvz95tZ@f8ffOugdHBz0h9v7vcHBnre30@81MN44ValfjacgJdlM/tjt8H7drhPM9tvNg@Gw1drdG@wcDA/aza2t7d7@zqC5vT3cb3lbW7uD9n7voPd@qS2BpwAMVvFd3DuyHPjxeuGusMLbpbbz/w)

(*switched back to static TIO link because `Run code snippet` button just shows `257` now*)

I tested this answer in Google Chrome 75. Polyglot file must have `.html` or `.htm` extension.
The idea to add HTML came from [this polyglot](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly).

Main code is on line 149:

```html
<script>document.body.innerHTML=257</script>
```

When browser encounters `<script>` tag without attributes it pauses document parsing, executes the script, and resumes parsing (see [the diagram](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/images/asyncdefer.svg) [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)). 
Then a question arises: why resulting page does not contain all the junk below line 149? – I don't know, but it looks like `<Wr#>` tag accidentally opened 
in Zilog Z80 code on line 2 plays some role in this behavior. Anyway, all the browsers I tried work the same with the polyglot, 
so I am pretty sure it is standard behavior, I just couldn't find it in HTML spec. I tried Google Chrome 75 (most recent stable version), Mozilla Firefox 59, 
Opera 11.64 (Presto-based) and Internet Explorer 11 (all these browsers have different engines).

Answer (score 2):

## 258. HTML+CSS, no JS (Chrome), 11990 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=257</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dint 22 8$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50) );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=  (^);instance Num(  );(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2qghUAQUSJAgQ6Obnbd7b3eSQ7Nv3DohGF4ACUE2gCo0qkECz2TEz3pjVWAqvPJ51jEZr3ZFseaW1I6x1rFdyWApHSK8OhZ/0A1p@2VBsaP7B7DknswoFEADZIylii0RVfpw8mXky8@TJr5M102v/8pcxfNix2xm1Oq7PfMvzWaNvX1p9ne2M2GPT9rKZVUlCqO1@a9C1HN/LSzFmMOZYV@zQqdsNcGO@e2E59jurD34Zxnp9t9U3u8xvmz5YbAjF9qzO@@57n9Xdbtd0Gh5ArjJ2bIJnc1C/YGbN8/tm3bddB7zWGHvhdMxurWEygLD6vb7lE/osAxT1Cwoz6bPO2DO371kYfd3yPBcdNxjbsro9f1QCSw4gzL7tPt1@/vlU4E3GPjchZb2ONZxKi5FmL22r35gKYRjsq7ODg2nXDPtScx12cDt9xip70ffMjjmNf41tD3z30J92z7LtluWYLKNv6plpz3W20zdvBdlgfctsNO2OpdtOnWmsbXV6Vp@hC2u6fSgy3@rk0rl0dXscUq9j2NzYcwptMXiY2W954OleWmC0oCR6ttVgzb7bZabjXUFMxmZ6DI9oNyerQx0SCBWNvfEgdMNinmP3epbPPSG7Vp@8IWbWsZ0Lide@477bGNRtpwVwFtC1N/ApT55Uh2Al1hN1WEcDixEVOBgk4dTtWtGy8KDyQqq9nlW3m3adE8ca@pbjQX49ndlQdld2p8MaVgcCjLHXk8xz2cCLONU6Zluv6xISF2Nh3YsOs1m912PcC7IBSTpI55jVdd/Y7B34d9oeG/a6zLO74O3X3WbTstg7q9eG4KzbkBquxOCp96ZyFtqWLYBxLMjd7vE3QDcfyek0IWkNVovAQToozZRj03GBfH3mmF1eG@q9EeUe0IQhmq6ro3vDtTwn7rMrt3/BalbdxGxjZJ7VapqDDsRoN7E4oB7YHuu68IVCdBgkCwL7SAvEjZFJMzOC0QTFa/WgYWLxulhdoKyDUr7qm1A/@p4oR9/uQu2w/bjHLNOzkWNBEM9yGlQzeiEvcyG30UJnlzY0PCDFoE@4PatPVZ/wMswFoDTDuqpc9W0fagTmYpsdW2afnfUtS@X11PLqZg9raTRKiMzFGHzMiE4Vc2srvn90EIcKykPoZg8qZH/17DtfSCbTi2y5WoBfUZYL0v7zPXa9fI5mzjOhEvf6iqmy4gfmpc7PLfgNjVqq1b@RAKsEVOmwlNvzU6bWgwRqPiQwZaIRTdplRu91IhGzrakyiDQbDtWA0gAmwL5KUs7qg34fufuYqOYFZLrjOi2gJ2S2P3B4ka@noQig/jW8JLMuLawDvIzcK6LwWRtqCPwDaISz8A6HCApdDjRFQdEgXs/tDAgOQno@tkegCgRFjIdN9hVrmnYHg4A/ouKp7lseVE4MM3AaWPJd27EaOguSQVynD23xEqIzASk5QGvoRngLJQqAoSBcyip6ffzN3260WoBnu153@w1RXb@Cyl6nrtGkxELnxrDCuo7ZoWQBXBJj58EhgkuzYzeIy5nOSERBiaBYr9xBp8GooV7Z0OTaJjBbCxhE3bd4JXcHPqQxybrmBeeINq@5kPGuWYOCpQgobsq2xh7vQinVoZlTndG6A7@ZY1pvn8W91CvlUV55tHRuQeJUXV1ZTqVaBahw@go5gS2@qOZ8tT3RVXi@6bl2Q@qN/LbrZJhWZ3K96PYsR4lP4Ign4/1aXNWRUytqwS7W9abtNJT4FtTFEkQcVwv1Yr1s5yuFqeDRKAHNFaLB5mopdVVGVkON4jLVBeFCB072lSZMET/XqyLJ0VuPOCNhpt0uuUOMRBesly5WEOBDutexrJ6S1g0V2QTCzcw3eszK6RQOkeG8XUnEY/FENOuEAXI6kVFsrGe2i2yr02ujvAFEcbwe8Nw@1t26CbXHw07NB5EuyWpUr6knBM5CPPHKigPXrgEjDeoRNUne5DC8hoxSYBg3ocmWbDUiDRmYALRl37vFjTsuSgeUJux5gHU4GKnZgqKBwDwj2zwjPCZymczShQMMBbHVLJbTajY0AmxuwNNFnY/kDcBXMxwGsPFGEuE9XXOEvRoXDcYNBvs0k3WBPfRHrG4hzwHmY/EOBSMZUPvzQO5lbpOltUw2O9nGbjUxv5/a1r4LTPpdamFLwsxHGxMyGtYEMbtjOq2B2QJ@4ToQxKzXrZ4vGBXkxPOBFU33N@Soic5T99rS8uPpuKkTCcSjcRzI5Hnpia7QRO4ixHYNZDIU/fhYgDXsPrAl6MmnYgeAy6nI5dcIMpGA1/KcJAQSAFQya2jVBz5wNajAV2273oY6i6lzOF/kndB09OAUjR04u9YMo8bEGKWHGUlPhU6YjLkoNCzR23igc0VUpQkHKvyow2LMptedgdgNkwgdQcRVT5k61L07cHZdx52BFAgZokWQSR9eDiCJnaJQDB1XIHZRYw0l5bCIoMyAa0DLh/rX9v2el4d@wvbbg5oONSV11h8d@kcOVpaU3x/ZvsvNtY5bA7bsQftMBTGk6oOaPZzKELmFZfjGky5BAGt6rAg999sB1Dol3vSAYZL7LgJHvGRi3ISCv2UAJCAdCKU0PWLFB8BUTkdOXZEnKqWcZDK2XVkFAwYMSfMFCm@TyXwDTtOpRLBoYvQUQqW8fp0MWkQmRfQITsmSHkxk7Z5plB7IMryaZsez4OsMOh20DhzO5RQuK6jsWnrwAFibQtHZ3V7Hrtt@lfuyhw@FTMGWYIyHYlMTZSYVwjwQg2kdGArAiO6HQ@u@e0rCrqJCRh7cTERs9ftun8frt/vuFSMHBJOiRN11u8jd2UsSuFCChmGt7eDwXvSl1JWaM0WIsE8leTke19@4tqNcx5eWluL5eAl6zKWlR2DaQtMjNCXA9IhMGpkQTkcThUiSCX3LFALdKvGbcoB5qFawOQyxt39n9xSznM@vVpJm2RDfDH5VoDP0GACt4QfwxNViEY2qKpeuIKN6rTmZ@13s9U7rfbsniPCFeWlyu6DCKpEBCs7t48CggMLLYpp0i32QLmAwUG8r/fh5OX1eOb8@byTOb@JJDK0WzGINMgXxKV291XcHIIao5bW8ZlRUtbwKwketGE/HVxQlp8EwDkYi6mc5NWFyaitxC3pD5fw8DkQV9CnX233CN0xmVDUkFaQDBR6QtZW4fp2D@GtqRU3EIawaT8LQrRiPA2XqSASPMo1taYJARydfcsLsJhISNW8YleLvVncKbjjonQx@PHj3DnkXx1ELa1hnYHIprycAUodOAKuj59SgNfCqNRny0Yk4PnebfFS0i6/9pweSNaTS@vzoYP@kSNG0Te8CZAqthbApkJWBKv2GDtygM2hY0iwYYBtgqo9TgnMHGHmrXmeaywhMq/NERLqLOpuDDXgNCZ4u0zrdySx4bUjv7kQeCAm5U8hF8ks9SBIHn5mmMMoD4Ni7p08npsi6FyBPsLrXQeFb6/MMgDW1wh0b9AnHGHl2SGM0BwRMqFsgXzbCuQDHdTTkhcFwzo1GxCdEAILcUNpCScKegEHETXsIQ@IYzqcI0R8lVpT@d10HBqeW/pK4ocyAkeNslaXPlP@PuSCl171x6wRJH4y9jlkHfj@J7lxm54AQOFAqNdtHLdxCPD04oHH8XXkEUapuOki/hk3j1IHttZG8MJbAXqDfBKriIBUnd4hqh6wOUm4LKG0NbZ@PWqGFn2KQJ6anqDhO2ubjDKxlKCNjooKZOxJg3TqM8C2QldGXT5ewfefS7rsOElnfB9TAigpYBlPIZ5EXqtH29mFmbz59ZyEHit1yNiK0jWKdJm7dg9bluB235bIVAMCqqeu8Yh86OMMJoxzf7EGLst8RgbZbLgz1J@ugZYVzpuur4XjTRMgUwetvoBdgszM9BpiT59PD7@6DGGJk02lIf2BL0xNmMoJlOo/oWGdjALEK0MF6gyX5XavXHvUnqpPninkTnyYPqWHymSwTREhIlWjh7yhotJFzF2jngVcjMM3K@z6NCXDyLjqunsj9hLTCmw3kMDbljK4BKSaQ3irwcfki4zpPTfCtcKpAa3Zd30x9pQOLxpeEErJmM9lLxZfiKU3Dt0xeLFNiqYZ1mUIuNcY83LfqM3EPLaueQl/s3FhgmEmewHMOac7hcegF2eTfgAZhyOn8txIJZOyUujBunmjo5M/aA0uy6m2XyecwxIjmTIYOog1jZQ0oDwIgjkvCYGJFSPLdAQzrGlbH7tr@Ic3Zdxwcu@jEvHXkWsJ3F/jNGMGxbYFAziccxp0MzquP@yinxeFPgJMTVhji65ykfauRWhlje@a6fRhXesygOYVMSPqu8Ei5Xq@h@0NAwEPtU//uBf3886O9/erx9tmTYmrg9VMduwY8omFVuzCY7UBzmPNg2nCGcB/qju24XRtyFKB8d9E5cV2fCw@4cHC/J4YBAxxP96pPD3dOtk@@EYmjHt3uDjompjG/PAUQ4jglmIVo6m7NBdnCGczFBMLF0c7R0wDLFy@eHm5X9/aPj84iaN4MOrZpDFO9i9a8DH2BIMzQ05z0R53G5IoODVMnZhEEs8ExV4HB2JRpGrw1dOOR4qhMRw8UkbF71DScBTZxnrvPMkZ6c7NRM3M5a71RX1vbaJrNRmMtY@SyzVw2k03Da2N902LvCVzTrCHN3ICJz4rgBBLGAYmnj6GvBRIODEXrILGMZqYr9F2QuHo2a22sbZqb9c3NTTOz0Vg1M7kNy1rfaK6l09a6kW7WckZudWHiIslA0Wps69IMELQ6nCwgT2B@CnwmmgNPPMh6V6yRyWTW69nm5mqmkU2vNWqb6WyuUTM2zNqmlW6urRoZo1HPGPkgLM6oApdoQ4GhVOmAaBp4aQZ4qlLQmUaLmFYZg2VowXCWV5HF9IJlZBw4CI819BiIRWScmhXuWXQPlpBxika4r6N7FxeQx5IsWUNHAZgjQFxH1vu1wHETHcMV5Im1VWCVgn/O8p8fSGC@NtI3iPwK16Aj@bs2DHK/9JvNCecMOV9o2JV1xs6r5MxXoCfXfkVmb3nNBA7xrRE@vnI9E98tr5nAIb4sx4cr3rPRTfnMAg2RrRMyXCGfiWvKYwZgiGmDMEVX1cd@OfKbt6Qu4prpPTdQiHuTcPPV8uobvlpRFYvlWJt5AzkDSeypC/LzUxvn7ZsTLUYKR@DnkhxMI0xOJI19MuNlEqZdzl7fkaOIODOwnQuXBs6hqZrWjSxiCVF0Lzq3QzZhqEGvCdBbibrtw/uvbq1JrxkA2OlOz8yRB017iq4fulozdUIfnACdlYLJqdyJ6GtWcwCjoFTNdtB8B5i2mSPIZq1mzwMFSuDmg@A7AyzPTgYwEs3oa7oRDHtx6QR4Np@HPTs8IsCaSYO4yfl/NkF8f9D3IZT4/tfvNaAQbhdR2xzRWDA0VB3riupHc26JiaBoodfs0h33@kQYMt2Fsm7ikqvZCQ2zUVPpa1rb7HdxyCWKGyoovqAmLKhrPOV8Lib4zo4kz4jIk@sMzLG7rD4DmmCnlkR4ZDTI7rhmg8jAh8K2RYH6WNi8GKwhHxRGBB7oeeZFNGPlgo23CvjtgT/gb9wdcFcx2j38LWqiAjKdNWuGBSKyWbOtBYXeNy8GDVcDSY@yjAlbnwE7zj1N1mnNjnnBjVU0zs4@z2DfbrVAnhDfeWBXbRjb0KA0dUWfu@qF5wy8nlaDwvKh4ZCNmkJ3QQz9Dn/PA7HF/rnQMJ9qdode9yj0sHJRdQGRjgiNW5q0CNHsKTJ3zNoIh@rtT69lGCEJOMBzivVEIr2K3V649hvdijQ/PPaVFH5zc3ZovpmKk2TW8CrFN1FpfAKZ8iy2Vd1RsNBx2V2zo2UaEeNcjh5MHY9NM0Bp3kard0wPqpYvisO6hOKj16Lqjj1THYZd/bFpQWUfJyfYAjBvNVmwLdGq627H9rBpd@Zx0OkFuHGcuJ2NXpEpaXsWYRskM3ltLTTN5gtu3cel3DkV7R5cjq@i4jp1pObo7jyi1d0r/M0VLdrupcXfszu6dzNTdQ@OpXWoStj1mT1Ko35XTcXtQPSaTceLmeny652Z7pNtIJjiiA7Q7lmvPbvjeuyU3ovI0upDMP6eXaOjFLRNR6P1oKh5djCRqB7TxSzrnHI1Oy23s55rpUx4zS38Qb@JfYL43pf7hdzLMO7mXoF85DqG@M5l@xep/sVdZUdLE31ctI8YF/TAs1iYWJScn0EYSeBOnNmZO0jnKKSe4uPleQXQr7evzFHw/RV6lnnUDXqW3ojkbRD/MMBmDgx@n8vgv0psa4tja9yPPd1Cu3FXJiKFe9GxoCOj960iZZm08YkhjHT6/syq2RlYA2smrzqqvbFwf/uCUcj9E5UW2VgWs504I4RznSHUOzF@vFeqsQ9H20IGY3ZsaOR3Sjoz@V0PZPQeDrmPwXCMhtsBW86gN1G4E6M452Qx5dq9oGW7jYlEos@ncqTc3fLUhCDvWfRbOLjig0Fc2yquptNpId9E5q8nLIsGXath2Dc2f09ETC7jmMewOBvSjxhnxzGeSoWity88DSc178edMvNmBAh4czPl2I7lj/A9r0hmcdua63Y@pQiB6TZslN9AKsWFn7uK8pZsJHaDsfHch4czJ7XmvFkP3iGJ0SlQDwfei2pDdOr1XsWs4ZI1tNLWlHXxPFBkIveuWKCbp8klvnWiM1/wFDMqhp7TNxa2SC7OujWrY/LPcH1tEb5NfXUhvlBkEXIyrW3hehhfARuvqMam@FZvBMSyGzDIaVtdi6wLRgdm483ACz5zgYYu/mZ467TeOC9czwZG4eB7YrUtIkr5rgPDMt/stywc13RwVVy4zmPOwaz6TOIeds2Wxc9VLeKe46kO3DrMR4Nj4@xJjzzfdVaHYHzrx@KqAI3pwhp5wXcmwmejOpTnoHv3VN1Uu6/TRqW7GrqemrmYcIes6LTdttO22nwnUGib1zygRvr8RNyiTED6W@06I/4U3aUUpWzH7XTuQ1nkj5xbum5zZpr28ZxWA4J@Et6RWQMP8blzChD6eiIQdfrz2k3bGkCX5bm@27M0ss0D7eBkEX/P46LB4s6vOgu1cIYAKBJ8f1X8d45NW6br93r0qfY6A49eFFSj43WzivKAorlPrbB9vu2I11ur5dbqbfuuJNUs03fsi1QwI8StC0e2vQgVbKbtobPesYF4/ZGOtaEY9T/Fz@G8IhWTS7zbCg2zyzjPdgf9/ggp4bsu8zru1Zg/TO6fCKdx@eoDGualQKwMzvAmaQB31gU7yBYsgYiFxLkVjIRwFLg1Kw0CizF3Rmlie2ekdayu8tc8uWgq/5SoyPrtp0yJim0PNDloR2ZuwX2i/kwsRs/srJz2oOXdZnd8wr4BIha@Zpb0dgvPNE8VNC9U6IFMR3zm0TvTSeH2bfhWoeQG1sLVlezC5RWCMzqa6drwqcIHynAwd9qsY/c8/mZaMzNTYLi9hHwbajR72CzKp2E1@VoImu6S9LpuHw8RgUih1fuWV8epdOTIXH7i3MdxW8CZtQ4bAwewM7Nwe9V6ZvGHPZ729XOrZeL2yqc27rTszKgVgHV68foupN8ZmJ79nYHrWzPxTS9g34Xumdmy608mKB8gCygq9uDxz0S1R6fbxL9q2x6d3wgMC@acsJLxaov1rAry/qzR2tR0fXgwevG0SkRQEnu/mXbIgj3ioQEXDNDfnBnXrJl4t0fjxhGZFk3C2z7NzIrvzFo1exPAouivBt3ewBOf2bHTPp3oFHX3gty9KxvYovYWuDFrmx1/9jR2ZGYWZC7RSY6N86Tw79odt8W@m0szENGg00ahfEaF24Hu@tj0oUU4MyowxX3PhVKc9ND6PGNvoU5Yq0yzHdtfPMHj@yaMkYIvZoZ3NngKMfUU3/rjT8Wgnc2myNOFEgz07aN6Bw/Ff@pIgLNdqIWndGgdjeG5@Wi9F9FYuwJh0Ls41lV0vLZw0SePXarrDHwNd/kv6lPWF/YpeTbMrUeqBlO@s//shRqtIbT99S451IKB4MDrjMamuRsPpiqe7YCwNp8XT0IHo4k9i1QanNBGzTvCbPfw9BSx/D131ojneAS9z72HTNCBDLp7Vh1XHu@M@7n7DEQ36Mp6wHS7JxZuGZjiJbMDYrCnbt3sAH0ad0ZzSmhn9BXjwbXZs2pQvp2xabYsNgvxnumbc2QnmjikEWBourOu2J2a1X9DM4IR87xB7WSCnlhDGobMrzC8FWp@vc4FbpyWm2gj02s7Xs91Hf4mJpyGj/FsMbOB7oFe919x13H/8kTvN3OQNpnbo0u@3cRq8IN787Lbt2puh78xC3PYgWPzzQVm37a81FPbGQzJjWkgu80e5vBtvGl9A6c5vDY0tisbxtjh7l7crMa3CntTIykQiS9Nj5b8Z49pJnYS339XUdvs111cOxOGT1w5ixwJu4OPh1ul@daEGhTKEBiaWR8EegXuSGqnW@vSa@6YJFLSJ1YNj9zV6Pyobw5nCZGTR8eE49ThrYClYcNfZ8oxjHrUuzuy6SHbJMXtHr2IoV/NrCZBdM9tq/7OVO/gpWErornklEkj2pkNaXITHIg5HUvz27jHMuX78xjGc/ti0LjHWlewgDLoWrhmPblyM7dSuV6baoQ7e5U@ZLh9S2zdxl2C0PQDM3JdbXtulUX08H@080UKOubq@hqe4B8MtRaws7v3BUDiB31HfO5T7Y5dz2/aw6MeqnFy@/P4C2YrC0Hgw5sDmlbmZQLK0xl0@HxHK7Kjq9ug8R1Ig00XTB1i4b6lWc6lRiqOhsFyZd8M9MjMLcPpzaHGHbtDr7xwPRA8tJ5H31TPOz58enSm9zxjwcwhbvgb2B1c3aOkBG6QQTLNn6I@pb1qi@XNvaOd/afbTGkAk3Ed9Q5osSDaa5s1yzdT5txxDvpa/myh78nZs6eJ8aFlpuy2@27XUqPeu6enSUgI@@J0wluczyFVQqHSCS8pTo6Bm90Xp9M9PdCLJY7ZEdcMDnyAo1mvD3CCB2qezghQUcxEQlUlEeqJe8W6qHQHA3l0WvTC7hVYOjAiodrQMRI8npdX2LLJtooss5ZmqlrgqieAqlA1BlaBNe0A9bbn2S0HkhCkgLQGoUYRrpDIYyB9@wHecpktXw/z6bxxw4pMzsusUuEpxoci2R/2SOXPCQ9eXjYrxeW4psWX4@dOnqXjIbjVgVHnTHBzAhYSix@R4JC@XB2YS7q8QmoWuMYU6A1QG1HbdBodi71waLUV8t/nej@4Upkz3EX8F3/QEEqaSBlZ1/bMDhAE9axBSbfdq0c83oBcvZ6JSp4Qx1UbZ4gxdm13m8Ho1a@3uW4mKK4XB2c5ofFFKHUDyzGfAwxTwWsOLkTi6VWfVwyemvAkoog4DBVkCoZFg64DckjDb3s6O7XpYOqgPz5qIlTdOX4fVxsaSXbIGhZu2KTzxrS41nHdCzqDhCn5iz/gem7o1LE4DRpET/qtIjHi4WKDlMvU6@4AUh0geWf1XQGiIJHNuj/ApWxSr0buKp7FJQU8UNu1QP0MRcN10OxunzJtn8VRcRuqiyjYTWV5@@Tzr8rpSvED66as//q9lHotCCd/pm2ue3KSBSCFG6xYUe8seI9940xeHso8wvBIti0GPle8PFDpHK9keCo7qGOu2wuaDUrSpDErrI1CE4WCZirnQA9Nl7SPUYW1rkgPDZ39c5C1k/Y7DxoYWFVCzVtdcVkZ8NVV7dRnWYgQdfmYYOL6yuiQMupUwSDLQ/aeEfsFUdrIpsHGCdlBNT7d4k6wnX81eswitWfVBrTV@DKjZ7JFys5ytbhVIhN01S6q0yq/Oh9m0tr5cGO/AoMDQdTz8@Fn6czXQHW3D6EeprDl7T/fu17WS@n37z1zxGT5Jl7gx0KATSxfHx8e75@ebZ@9OIVSuAlY2wE/HBbwGqxFdN6z7XZIURnQBaX0T@A/oW3MBlEVpqpK0ZN5BCpoLWvyMjdGWNNE6DuCzwrvWRH/2wCCpzVtJoU9A9QCkyobUg0zP@ihujUmwgqVUVTLbOw/sAGFhMHDNzN4KZFKZkUglgbEuiep2PzMPuJu96HYnVgWk@3RTBCkWBhfOfTnWZxJgpu/l3z3TM/7u@ebY1mcb4JZkG8ADV2DMAfbh09fnOxPBgs6eeK6xc2sOJLKmTO2NC7pBzqySBOECIir00WZyRSAW0VnxjV1Wv6VBdkSzLHe5YGphlL6ZWlcMYEyRVQWWxFSiKJQClC@QUFk@sQsiOGRJAZ9dATdNc9iyAQO5BB1kHBdFphjpPRUxyfIBmIV5Aqa3jExccGv415U/EkGLQ6zhn30wONtbk5XFfY6HoP/SK8UmDIVNmSiOzMqTGMZ@HUspwUZDmDVAu@j2DInhLzM0y6H6UVllZCmxhuTFoToJIg4aQq9dMfseYEwGGPPXd/Ks7cDl7RZBMwklC9IT6rJdctS0XKNqaQlA0bgIH0H/RbhOzw4LaJ0xkUz4u/ROjdwsKMCIK7mVZw39/uoDpkfBOb6FjnJXaHaL@gqaVLFE6q8QinBY5e2Z9c6vH41UcbpAKfE3IiMo6pg0mPCtjseyCQN6L5BQvGxqwXhRKfjifyMouYwOQZ1Ug9FxiSTJYT1irdVvUFXeoWDxNc88DLBEWYvgjO@taRpQLmW7QR6gfOoKJjmE/LM7w9w92EpfitIkIQ8mbS23@1EAGcovTy3Uh9/87e5ostzH8w/EuZhegdsvy5sTTD/RuBjGGD7Z6EtA7Yfc9urFBbZbe1@43SGihrmHuiEyvlYvpUxZAyBhmTKUFjkWNxfHR4zr46Kd7FAu@YwUlbIZoJxCrO7UDMuqaARnMcwLscxHqX8FdQTqFxQSVDGQbGG4rP6FQUVveVTKUw4rhPptA3UGvKtGaT37e0A9Z2CJJZaz66vGSlIpHYZICRVNC08lcYRqmoeGKN0afeKr2t1trW1xWSvbnas4nqBV5DUsvlqVX4dJnQZYCU@WigzCANBxiHArySCKctmwlAxKPZmcSOOjK3h8voGIqFCBgBR0dkJlFeAzOkKUkFldqyhT2LTKBgFAdd23Iii4wCRBog4btTKOd0mxyfNcHIz0kr1aDHILxGMRvd5eVaNLb9i5/65UxHaWRnUvp/PqL8OmP/JDJWtvGahcp7bukKVaU2fmBv2@NRxcY74AFLLlEwqs5oy1tVIDZUFKkgvtvf3gBJaOHCMumW/cXve9u7@4RdHx6e3dEYRZHwaLM7ipa3EuaYny5XQEA/TPUnUnYPU6bOdg4CU0VSNZ2kRYrztdjqZs2KbTumc2F/yQ3234yaPWxEZ6fsipike7YC2r9/GPvZNRQB3@ZmiW7Eq6vVNubJVOndit6J/P0sPcExfwcoFpnOPtADHp5OJSQx1/p@hzn9PD06sG3hcHc8x@u7F@PC7cIh4cPAAC3AASU8FUPOYJyTgiM8AjbW0ZPilAx6xPj5LRNpZwxRFIM@C6wmwaY2VCgptem3Ta3fsmgQdeAM1THJdOIGyl1CLju71OravqBJNgRRRDAImpohLCob5oU6LywrpAiZcSbZIQV@AT5WgEQC@@PHAa7NjtxeZ29qzAtMJSCNsb8BXHi32xaALcE36nFjIYi2QTzQIDISKh0nlo2poWUI/3zCBOhAhvjJq6RMZ17uNrDJU9bY1bNgtYOCKmoSW/pkBYlWoQQAzTTr7nDjwOE7hz/EsV5Skn6SmcThGbpZN3XYa1lBBvUP5Csin6B6/enkZV@VbdYB0Re4G2uWmlEYGDdH0RYsYK1ycamyb4c0EU1o9NzdRdxMqQ4BigRhP/f5TMEL/pDS7Zo8pA9Jm6jGdkVU5V5yk5/dVppW4QhSHJRI0qoYPeYDUjKBNMlHFYQrOQyqpIpQOunpOAz/v7B4rG7peATNForJlnFHbha4c56JUCUZJECRPaItYtiyPKeK1V@c1D8Kgv0Tq1Riq9JzhTUo4ae7eRVpQrlnpYUQt1bgFcqpubuZFaUyymk0G1eI2l9dTgHYGCwmkVKCvONsOVEMl9XibAS5tAFt4/KXlOBYQCOpM14Q@2BxAJeuryeBWkuRYqTnFEONJfCIOy0NCJ5Wd78evO7j@vZwq0ORM4Qb61Nfn2Kk2Rbc6Sv2PKT1VuFaWO8VRCgQdtaQst4tGYnUlkVh2VpRlB7v6hw9xTudmGSSJqg5DpCEAacsdtQD1GSSP4rJTWDa3lOVGMbNCIcAKg7RrCPDBS@nXy@ZNavkh9NRJcOnzxqsse6QvM63rxg2kD1vIcioJdeYa1QvSlSQY/bKdSGAa9OUqJuBD6vw0QTz7/DRF00cFIY2mWl3R3Ka4algSty5k4QQUzqKggbFnkLGLMwrVAHis6nx1lt8c2YNH/CUeA2O089TyouK/POlzf8Yi@F2cVJlx7aRcYSkQcKgAEdGaNFUVmMkvfxkz1pmsLD9aX@1cJuLZdAFeRmGDZdlny@eZtRiLPTZNH4bsqZXr871c65JZzcz6W00r2039beX44vj46@FIPVfisd2jV7KxBqAbbJN@9302WGbOwz7ticVWUlIstWI83EilXr9@DSIvPuWSXgpA9Ipa1uKVsrIhHLqljY2V5HpuJXnyOF6FtEB2VSWTUU@ZbafYud3zGg34uW26IEiJ8Yc9eoTxgQH@mXDrDptkHG5brdZg3xxxdzs2wM@BL8I@@@7Lly/R8JIe9u5EhI9xjAJdLF81szFKZCad@Ys/WbpJXh9Xt/7i@92UtYSfI/z86OYZmk@N7GdLS5/t7KytJYFw3Hz83eNvtre31/aS2eNy9tGall7a@vM/W1rKZLYyqaWK5xmVePniazmTXpP1v/i9ePX4@Dueh2WHzyozwIjvHPwMls2yC/YOnosmw38yv2tEzCaaa8132EGCsFwkZhOPZ1fjp6/iWD7vYoZhxEb0V6WsLTGj9Gjjv/3k6G3Mj5UyqZd9@Pqxt7H1XIwbwQC21cB2GSvFthBs/SY2ShWLRTBu/Ld/D@FLXwAe9BltwauUDXCtj2IlrUhB3sdK62AwMhmI9//53vekWGkIiSiVDg9YppRZEdXEyD00HpLJ8dsgYJzHjNza0WOy2tbjo0w2s4Vmx8KLVdowHEUmYxiZcyYKzxBFiNk18M0dWBvMWKZujAWg4zJnQY1ioiZABaE6ws3CgaoNd0DvCbiX56a5spFYyzx2Ci8jz4TlH@I5wRus1pcev95LpbZK0NPjk88/Pq@KZpZiGznZdR/j5F@BPRWuBXwNXU1zARx@5@So4SMIGMsVk1VOpKCVBT5sbGNRp5igJQsb1K8At4/PX/5ff/nTv/wJ/f2Ufv9ZigX7U7TyZaUUPFCD5FJfvj4XVucZe8Yfx4F/@AVWdEEHMDlibjIWPqUSvuhf2MhE3yk34VMKLQQxDjIXjgUci@KVYh9SKZbHUroslaL5gScVWikbPOVkeBbJ3Th/Ij/AGh89WoI/@ocntOJ7iVyEM4HcfpZYacGzuA@QYuVYuVLhzXo6RwueEx1rnS5s1WivcinFNGBUicQJ1FImKjc854k7nhfw0/WqsKX0MdaYFPt7f0oSi13DU0loNzfl@JobX3cf668ShYL4BzmvENrw4SZIYeVG07ZelRKJMqW0XBJJ3tJYpcQzQG@9@moL0Ce2yltFd5d@ehXppVVelcpbk4EpfKX0@HECSfsYEJSWKwyGFlAaN1s3pZvy1s3N1hb8b9H7RnzB9Wbr1j99xs8cmLF/Bcv/vJwqnadEqyxVwK5DpQYXPXWOtRu@AFcuS7FrrDmsXCG1b0WtbKxnKxqjFrIC3CuVN1Yyq6ns8LP1/QwwAQ/BM7KcWkHDe@wuQeDZlGI4dNjkI4hNcnj98dv/A3/nH7/9t2CFpOH9euRbe4t/T9/h31sf/87q@HfyFv/O3uHfiY9/xx7@PavhnxQrMgYS2/KjdCd9mTYujAsw2CwNAnM73TYa0NmwtMXSo/SIpbuu0QCTBX9pMNnpJku3WNpJO4YBnmDwWdpHUxM@LfhrApY@/NnpNCJPXzKIpYNdGKlLpu/7KlPPpTKLv7ZAzNINPa2v29VKdr33thyvFGKp8/MUlz1ZZq1A6rFvbhirVvef71WrKaz858/co/H/0VE3al343z1ynx25XRf@j46Onp0DAyslHie0x/AUS4kt8XkUKxUenec1rLhBFY6lth6dl1Y1NK8noFZm0C3xic8YI3xLS@cSjM1fvrwqUD9buLosXBXIEFq5oSoABBg3QKiC6J/BBcKdv0xRj3oFzyXhJRsar8AzMHFD6uXVOUqQMF4I/4EcUevfw7/9/6//Zy@YUq6o0Aiub7YUelT8U9Xrm@sb8S6piiIsyhb8oQPYMcj1TQmNBHQNprKiVtSbG@4Gb0Xd4ghLGMdWiQKPAYFTxMI4KV7@Uv5@vxg3f87jICbBSFoRy4Dn58N0Wi3UwCVcCzDf04qSWqC9Nss1XAWE0aOhEkR2rVAwVrg5s5YpFNaEZSNXKOSEeVlRNm8/pfQjY309n1lbU9VCIS1gYZxYCIyAwvLMegEbeSGmYmJ5y1fSOBtJF2PE5bz88KEirlJ51OupDx8am@n370OnarVh96tVdF99/16uyrgtp7iZBXs69/49MJ246vaV5y5fEFY0g32WKVEMm24fcrUB3sxIZcZxtk3P9P2@8s7uJWXcDunJKimzTqfd/nn8Fz/@/vfP40XcqEGuawYiwFhYdmtrfa1UWl8D83oOMi4v850/Siuxaag3yymZZ5fJy/GY8DJyGyq53sTRn8W22KMSNFQPH3Z9E6PyY2tZVamNLPUaXAI3Y3OTO7K1dSWX2BR/xSWVlVaY@CuXy6uJtZWNlccVEG9uP8hUC9dmMZ5KxW@K12YeZ61uCnVxaQIeVDIfPlzdBGLm0oVzqVrd2z7bruJ9i7gmD70fQ0fi0BKut/b68TJNMWY3K2XMWOU8Hs8XHlOxG7ksi8ULAk6LA7dnuU3Kf8zzJLuJJxaHhHXqtxLrMWNjFbpV6FWlHm2P2kizBq4w95nbbC6BI5Qdq@FmAM/qdIKLJq7cfqdxZTesJSl2/HR7d/8smQEJJZY52N5NZk5f7MQMtGbHdvRmsVV0ONnf3jt6ASGOn@5vn@5/fvjV/otjcPekN@9MyzKtgWVdVQeDq7d4GYFVtXrgOn6qVt32zDdvzB49MErhzPnq6uPPf/jx5//Tx9/98cff/eHH3/3pL7796Q/h9wfw@zH//vjfbWbx/Ytv/9nvf/yd3wXH/wy//wS/P/nFt7/1Pf4j@5/C779E3P5U/CJw/CcBrl//xbc/@b1ffPsbP4PfvxS/n93@/eafzP799AfzfxjuJ7@/GObH/x5@f8hxBbA//h3uht9b8L/D4X7jZx//xX/g/38u/tD4ux//xZ/iS1j@6c/@/L98/P5/zGRyf/5vPv7wxx9/8JOPP/j@xx/86OMP/nHm42/9GyMdff3@x5/@0X//4z/873/8v9D/H9D7D@/z//Fn//Sv/s@/@r//6o/F70/g9x/A9Cd/9R@hrv7NH/0c/3/yR3/zn36O///7v/qbP/pf/@bX/zUZfpsb/t9/@e/4@6@//8O//sE//@vvfzvn/cOF72/v4f7tP4DL/dN5Hzz3ydenunz7K6Xn70KNcSxQB@jaB5YBKXZnZNF8xWfDvPQZi5VW8AGmXM5lcokVEEBXNjeBM1fIfQtBmATt9Kf/5ONv/RpU/38ByMD2P4MN/rkFvH5EFvb11xOeLEFzIFri66/RUwwav45C/Qgc3qdAHE8/fg8QX5M3f1gIBvH@bwQGcEyABXCTCSAY3OTJ3X/x7T//PfIIw6Lzr02gTAfOUehlBH8fZPVH2O7HuYlC/whZx8eff@/j7/3jjz//7Y8//3XsHLS1zeR2Evr2xdO8AJi9BxwCrt8HDgANHDTCIH9JyoBhaQunJiUj8fo1pH4JTDDmWpGyq2CTjBKZDTRDwATYCMlwmMA3/Etrmwwt4DIkV/iyBHjtJPA68IQ0LIIfgeI94gyNpRw4DXFyoQh4MRAPk6zmYDTDhjuEBUIWEyesulIc8oAJdCgRBqw2EjqdyEZGTuSKexBhcbjHEBciT0iv4fu6WMoVhyVE94GSADgSOxAlQOE15Ylh6QPYi4QT4KXh3gdISq6YSJRy4FLETCYotmSV4jSylDnKe4JRvtGdMdxs@egxNBnZyMl88gNIyQQ0vhNjaAQEcPA/T6yI7NB/YKTfCoaHchoSfbgb93@EzhReAABeTcM9evDTNEzNY/AeclQJihY@CY4BKJcgMSpACQ4ksSSkBJVvgiwQP6Th054tZBWIDrOzvLwMpq2SvCpXj2AQCaO1/kXe880@riGSJJln8vqmjM644Ylv5Vw@ptHmyt4KvA3431@i7cuUl8KKtBzHeYs4TxrEpSVW3TU3xrMR5JFsK5SFBAGyz8AHf48fgxloRN@xG0410H9CehWTWIzKHhpLkr/hoxfJPdKUyOFVUUqM7TSfzUPoelJPJsVXpy856MKgk6/46sskMjI@8KGVamasrzFVUujCLRVLqG6ROCY981o77hAGHUlZThrruPqkiomas3wGW6u0n0/D@xs3ny9@MNY2JPiSfYAXf4krqKDe4PXn@tYWln/pWqPZJDSC0LoulUpi4Z0ZUul0/wzAz46YkUnrDAYs12sbmbXsWjazur6e3cgYa@uba@vZ3Cpw1vV0NpMxNtfWNnObGzchtR4Dc0rmV2rZrdI/uvX8D/9o1jPbFR@p9DUb6jSDfiOVOkW@AXQZF@Hl87RcoKktouVyOZ3Ev8zqKrwhnUkju1FZWupca5jtc9p1eI3bHCCp0rWGHd8DeJj0QGIPwAkeiAOXIZnYOHJ4VBCbBPD@Tr5RQDayUJGhHM6hJnN0UKLX19eRnxRb@u53fVYqwcBDOzyQYtAG2yxYFtfsht7W6drNxqBvkW@Lsb3Drw5PD4@e63uHpzAS@IZlVtO6FLu5uWmGizlktdjR0ZGEzA9GeKsGhr@ps8FgQL41sN8MTakXfQrwkzIZLbOqrRqasYr/dxgy@H9/@Az8Z/ANoVYzEj@q18GjO8GU2aa0xRVPlILr1PWa2xjpNt4Og@fHipnsxpZQ5lTa8vxRxyohxHXD9nodc5R3YKB8g1s/82YT0F/X@ZaJvJzJ5uQbCEpBpC2h0aFEq9FlqKAVvPytXNkKdD2UpA8fPgxpA0j@0PHFTpDMWg7dmYSt8iF0dw8Nbsyuj41pNJ6hXo7nUEOgWTnsKW7o9l125vKNwztWfQ7Ebtuku/B2@y6MJ391mB3TueBeezZXEBB6PTFRQ7DXtf32HIgXvS4eFLT6/2AY9rs1SCCWMAfYgVe/47qzADbYi@M5uXwW6vPBTSOk0AfATw4/f3IW@Z7tb@8@kdbZztHzvalPVgBl2dP9g7PQusF9g6DZEMU3@0@fTlvFB3h2gSYQllh2IzAYLGb6ZlFOVuUyW6sU/JtHxtbDh8Zy6vgpTlEc94GOHTfF2PkHbesrrZQr9K2h7wzYi03goKV9KGpAstsv7iw3oRdoWWVo0TB@r0CudZym6Fh6tdSg9pNhuWXpGW5N3TT4OSvbk@i4I16uhhcp@hIqDGjgBeo4o1TDm8wHPTbXET7ohMa@3WpDT3TlBgBSzTQZ/D71gfDRGQag00IHn8dBbrd8OjPAcS@E3WRpSedE2cxlc5urmVwyt5lbyxrr2WzSyCSNjdzGJvQBaSNnrOeym0Yyt7a5ugYdFfhmNzekGPBuu5lKgTRgyDJ884DWqeN9IFt4sYqrt0tSjM/jsXeKqUJJh/YBky0II@PNdJ5Pu@9X7KKcWcOjMasGA4wmq7PYwcFu@uBAlnfQgssMu2lZbqAlm0unN3Zk2SKfXehMM7Ls8jDgBWA@t6TTO7uyPOAIULuQLLfRsr@OQxVZttGyu31wgPG8QUsGwwPYBffhlk5g2QAwBy2rqzTWkeW3ITqA2@YRrVFK99GCcaLPAffZBT9Z/jxITzoNGE44HMfwJMjr9rYsH3LL9jb6fEEZz/KkfomWbXpkuQ8WqISy3AJDq29ZjizXwIhVUZbrYKqPTHDDu1dQ44zjm7I84gRCEsnykKDN@oUMErlwx2iePHlitv2G1eLPqM@/dUga@NjDwf5B7fPPa61WrT/a3v/8BH2@@OKJ@WY06NdaNRGsVoXHhTDgc9EdTT@QxsNq1ezM9PkSfJwpn@qoamHaquZbSJN4WhhJt/oF@HwBPjPmQoccGzxdAK3hs9OF745ZI5/gIR/6Dms1uYAV1R/1LJy7xDZz4QAvSHbNet8toH1YXGJxJZ4cldfTlQK5s67C1Ot04Qb9mwrd74nSLAp36vWoPCymKzBW28iIQzyKfD7MZG05udR9ZGxm80vmIyOzlhjmUYG024yzuGY8UoyHK@@U5@qjzOpaXj5/9EiTy0blUcbI5dc3Xq0MZFnN4/vR6kb@HYi8cZBr8aWWNyqPNrKRIBsbCTOVyW9sqIUbIIgPnU9t4FvVqqJcWeaFqmKCsUtX1GvKLRtRTu1CUxkmh0WeKjZiamFYNApc9wFLTyFjitJA7TsDvEtPZYS0xQDl8FE6j7xZkY3NnAxpSKUUVUXGhKwEvq9fBitc4SdimDDyR2d5jV/FaeTWVR3PhFTdZpWuI2Ovo5Aot0sv8QAXHd4O9lnSUMvLS2co5mNfYDIUo2p4@y/pA4ABL9cZxfjcj7GxKUklIeUe84uQCsL6@ZNdHQRfYUNNPvoBXvru9nW8rNif8OFaZgKnM@jd9CcW7p6sB267/Fi1vj@EUQ0eHSlcay@1m2iIUxDmeRx4sqRAagzwjDaqNLIbzCyWwGQ2FIqemeoVZbNaKhWrxa7V7fkjGObxJXLIVBD6@aDLdhiHxfNewWmXanEH8p8uOKjVz0Lr8jA2lEoN1Fm0U9y5HuRRKLwpWEW60V6O4Rm5R05x4Hhm0zq2@ng86/AIumwLz0HV26/P9xFwF2h9faOV@swZ5@HQ4yQKD9tQgq4xQcKjWkzfFKKpVkytVFMLrWIZQd/ja0uT5Yqmld9XYNBWkErQAgujmFn0BjV@7WO6BuO19cIQ3IyNtUKb1Yq1V8NCv9iDEQYrdICIkZETMwsE/74DXWpVrxaHY2qsFssZGDulk8FoKoN775KZ9GYyY0CfCn0thITfBtjX4GfAD/wNHGspHQXGRnIyPUzrRtKwjKSSfm03XqtJ3913oEDS@TyWCxQpWeFrqonMSkdpuMzc0qiEoY0XKNlmss16drKtQKgTy@xwcFVjivb20Xoim4ZmWXgLae4vKw19R320VmgoO6yqggPICPDLsPW1QhP3FrxSJ2kMnKygLKlFz3pLFEV@QeToLUGBiBGlN@iW02xp3Uhea1XtpmN6/rKxkcmXB8tlzYD8pt@3tuTvluQKFM4NjOolFl2aAjGkAG4BX@CCy1j0GLv1ULbsWFCOxmamIECknuBUiqzgpeB8s68Sj29k4nE1XsCJlCVwF5yOWFIceGT8ofFIBtFHzsubGfAf87dbKeBDs3UYQt5IOMhiMEiLXUs31zdb0R1JX7LRyExogfUhY63EssRStGdAr8bYEpk0vUTTXdvF7dbJdkFAb@9KsTxtlhtvZ2Ln4nA001JLn7pTIbFVesW/57grB6KVSI9VmVXEUDOzCpluROyQQe9a4lTlu1VSW4kSS51LskzNm6925rIqTyv7EKM7IdjudVOwpfwzHCMyxczzZluuqB@e253r3KrGx5kKi31giZROG66qqQ8x6BluiNbB7rovX2eyQH3HDRxgROkD/4OOJJuVcWLHes16p5uvNl7lXj17cfTi6IA9Tudz@dzUzO7542TSiBvxLfYYxFn7ZB@GJ@@ZmzU@OF/wLYixQizfi6@uxVengxZjw@JasJytGKWSZmxl2COoqywPPKpprGvp9yVe8UrksZ4Bn4@/9rO14VYO7BkQG/NA02wiUyoZKxk11vv47b/FQ3TX@19tP2VxVGnwt3/2e5mNv/2zf0Vrp/GbArplVjdiAIlGY30jdn3du76@gYf7ZWOVGE/T2oYKZr6ub8RKKeFsbBhqzNO4DZKbjXnvhY4TJZPOgd/uEbfJ60DN2GZMiuWevX7P2BaMHUuNVsvOkCmVujVVvpyH8Rn8sw84NfZBW3pdLC2noALgPN8mBgimclZKpdIKzsGzeCmBB0IzWVoKKN8UKozPteBAZcWhP8tbwT@0v@IOK54H9sAbrDgNu2WxbMlgMLhJpT7@2m9lMut/@2e/ea6@r76vfgd47@bm5rqRif0S0rHglFYwOqG5DDxvhYZwVMPm3Een12UphpcUNhmHD8Y4OKrBM8pcwwvapEvsjInEVaCjCSKlQmAreNYkScIlHUxVC5IUimAkPPZb9SThYCuo/BPajnQtPUAv6JRYEXiT9GCMChy6qBqmXvU6g36P5CCFwhmVJHsIQSCGB6hMYInOyAgGpxkFllq5HZQnmesVoQ6ddS3PQ31CwH@lBxDkKdRSukWE9Uw8Z4WQ/GZyBKF0kkejDHFXIO4OD1AlV4VyzwGSjKeOB3JAupQe4KEREj@hz2b2FgAUmCo9AAJAHhSB2K6wLbaqsms7kSiM1Q/d4M4nPHtuBqc4JAyG2Bp4dCkIXEA4m6sYGPRR7Q4TJVy3oo4BEo6Dz9AXQTDG4GRDgYQOat0bFeCiA7sKZY09fDhOVbFoN1RGOUL8qH0JVSaNdcXcigCQBUOKzxp5OcmcRAIL@8FktQOKJyi5UOs0MoyBmnicBq03kgT/9660WCOnioo8CpgBUV68VdSBZBAYyc7LsI76o4zMhsrCxNch7XVKFKmhCMdJ58PPdNIGU@dJvJF@GQu050l4229Eqhf1dvoYDwO@NMD7VPCMMmcG4oAO17SPzOnQD0KHoSArdoegm3YfxGhabQgUWiirhorBmqELpYN2PGXWGG5Gyqr4oVAIjWoPTFQhIOJZomOapHvJ67kO6Ryg85u4ZYs0QXkS17DAkz1wrkzSHsRjoR1OkRRxlUxY80ljkMPVInk8LK5s1Pow1Atok2RWSyflGplNpnA1X3i42wnRqRSIEgyjIhNpXOtYXUjSqWUxPPfu5VOplu23BzU66P7MhnrVPrCh23C8lLi5JXVlX9ipM1S6qLlNkFbFwaoY@8rs2KHOGXGanFRGdWy8ah2LVZk4GeexzHoSxL0kUHb8A8Lmca4RT7@lwTvJoeC3AZ8NbswlI2GXlJF6@7tqLClVlcQCUgfSx9tZLk0nQl963ktiHOaNvODYK53DArseslxomfzsSxwPv4SHsiRxPrdIZ0d1nATuKSBOBae10AgipnUJEJohYR8DTLMeHCPDVgy5fUAdALU9aFmoF8Lv5/F8ZRE1Jil1aHqCwTvsM7aaoTuv@YljcUAYcGDRFyexgx8ExXx4fgMKRucjbOAr0Dq7DfCLoZoUXv0wfFC70Uw6UsbVmy0JdNjpUFyoLw5DBJZsxIKtg2u8gqwvgec6pHBGSpYUOQFoE7Iqc9Rh@OngvLZLxEvy7DamJEMMgtSABUWFHdPjigCFUoerqyud9IoM@rZueaih0cNbp1K9lg3SqJvyYSQtlOvbeDOKuPVpbNK4hla8pOzRkO4G23w44l9JauJJx7cDu28p8aYXxz7wEnhlr9WlQ9t4nNqjenNgk8bSukILYJ6oZplK8jqoZnmsZloufoNIGEM0w@QoWU8CsmStfpFsXjUKwuOS2h0gh8KyAkdU@dUPLF0vMNm9Zgjh@rR5MrDXOhd1t@Oi6CHzicRx1DyHAeQosAp7zx5CIMe6Ytv9vjlSyF9FaKynyoikGzaC3p18wAi9CbvmmnHsYXlUmQg@DIND3xWMPVgfj2xL14uRcoVE6D/k/kPwH3L/4TjSINrysMIlL3S6wexg5UYNLAEkohkFMDdcn9LYhzCDXMwMjgIhRxNuN/CrFyl0QG9ug3IsBhUD6gSpMVNQf1r5vOJ41tVKJZFqQZ2WiRBQ4oC6XCGaXjVCM1K/c9npud6Ek4MKSqDzEelGp3pb1AZeVzCPYQFRxeD0slGPRaur84kS3u@LDAMGFLfAEyWAbV@x1UKoQZI8oeKU5TGNecLKIjEVErKEl3ADqYiTnhM2iqgSQYTuYZYgmeDDgpYj9O8KJvCyj1cVBrAaKYgnVZjxShwoOdVUOEspUCFFUqVpQTKB7CiVFqezEvhDUZSnvCLZvBHlH03@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@ejdOVAwogp3Z9QvlqCc84xDJNgNmVQd5HnzbIKowzx2PBEljF4rGNV8hvdBtt@u2QLxDbXwYegr94Rg3Jsjs9SgtSWbiEDUfUZ9IzUGpJ01VBP3yk4OyLzOKqYbhM5MIJoiRZP1pGiNl@zOiq86NjgcL4jv99PSeRtN7uji9NKqeTjMfahe556dFvaqMMQDgOBmrdycjKZTf3krORFJCZxSgeIB7J7FB@3EamNJtAN0W4HoT6kcytHmkkkMk/Kt59F9cgEHw/fsWn4lXNJ2OgN90cduXQprRvWDxRwHwQxV5z@3owqq9d8@4ABbkCHaAsgLIq8S4HNT3Ag2zB8NoTw6XPATiO@o8bsO5Ve9pb06Re85IU/8yyS4y84tor9qwOubIaigCMhnBG@T4BEZmxK/ul3FkdMT0XD6oU6CTUqPKYpHoHCg/p8qYycuIquBbMBzEDmsPzXxTCg/n0w/9b7FmnLIr8tlnEPjj8RhplSYl4L1Rb8T15HX4/QGCj/L@h5ckns67myBAB7GCnxxHqy5inydKmKV79AghrD6ZZdKIE3Rbbrd3uww/jUR35xQKNxKoGJTyhCbfeSVuLyrxSK0I6iRfz7lflbyr0t27zkWqGkc2ZmG7n9aF3MKMOwTqdSWKkbssLDHXucUT0I3m3Zw5vUp1BkMNQxKn820aV5N8oUo4BD6EL04gfQVfRNiy/CqvUEHecI5K3DTByKdr9iJSi3ABaRywRKgY6GunZESgpMAM4Nc3YZz1uXHWb8VZn4gzbAGTUUaApPpElKIUsHgWFUHHavpzuDN64SAZPovYNjyOa/ZxWuI6bsfzdpLFL@N5YMhxK57fV4Apxxvx/B4ZvHj@lAwX8fyXYBi3rfj7eD5oFgjQBysZHqO7YOFor8fzu4p6I/moUj@IV4/nwzIFmEfcShQBUmC@QWrEJTPHFdn0@xZ0bCRUJhnWGC@J4ySacEnSLw3/XHc2v@MBPHHOcoWAWYIZE51GpMfg8UC3EWhVnNGS86I33z86oB02Y@Xk4J@AwVw0DKEHMTwWn2RGPGHoSysU8IUEIt/Mz04RMyY12N8jOSJ2qKFUyJPxE/V0kgcaCvmXAbiiTipGF@GD8ppEwQvwfunEwPPSeSs5QXSUIlxjVWckC4n6Or4gU1jWU1r/eelHS4jmrieB8EqzAISXEqGN8HSQ4WixDSPrub3JSkK@uKvNjoah2TfeKLH2TgUjriBa5hxvchY5Q8YQbfzqouxEwmHSJlgQepbTFd7Kwn6BeDF6jXldRFLljQ@SEOE50MKt@oWF1XZPGAmOs5sk9RXzuqEgLI@SONckm4TAOqoZGJg@jz0cvO6j8oFPG74GIYc4qaIggkjIMBbOX91PkN9dLr8HAnVAhKkIZgnWs7vS2@L1wl52KuWdcbS3CxA9k2xPnSkchTGMSQ6jg4hkvqiu3RLxcQsHF/J5pCH2KWk/IFs4JriDbtNjC44LpYT@5aTjRQYcLzLzCXVbIulc6oHQomNMAg/PeJjScdYWp5VnfFYRow9NZJudTy7g/mQBRwsP8VEG@lMk560cj4zh2ta4bZPKSnRBlmrkGWfktPwZFvPYEdg9LcWGy7DgcFQ92Tt6/vQb6HQ3NjZU0UePxunDVouTqmE/zjHT3tuwP5gxbMkkUWUzLl7TreV4ReDSuSPf4iWcWYMwgFdVBNVPtHFV8LIIP59quxCOw0YoKnBdjJuBOcGVUNQxscu2BV19IIjlKyumQBKIt0DvJI3WVJyThdqBt15Vq9R9Vau4GalaFb0YFk2wwq3@MraUGnh9upuNK5S9kiQ64Mn2jtjLJ9tn7OzJPjt4sfsl@@boBXu5/fwMD0gev9h5erjL4Lf//HSfjWcU8EEl@zigBLruWXWrWwOWnUmn1xhh3nV7I853lF2Vu5@aXfbErVu4HrXlmd3HbW7RHcsv8VD7MBwdiWuGIaFd2/f5BVV1QEfCTYNOYuH@dQawNRjTdnHM23UbdtMGWAnHvj3b8oIDRKxjQwkCvw2O5CW5kIQK/2krEF32RPd04UVPAI@LNIDG9MYXi9keD2A1dCYIFz6fTMGz/ZNnp2z7@R7bPXq@d3h2ePT8lB0cnYD1@JvD558DPQ9Pz04Od16gFwE@O9o7PDjc3SYHnoC0zvAILN3ctSgJOoITVeoXuMRNdy2GtuisM4CBBM@uTDqT5rH4wEHuY5sd@53ViBckvAqEn4OjNQEWXsTFrLe4lBms@dJ@AvmFR5dZLKfZFsUGjaUE7a0gmit0e6hWGBceuiOGl5pYBTqZqpB5fFkKbcpp2BaTd3HPCc598wOs1JYD1BDREuBGVMEGlCIjHd3xeHKLUJYgtnrHRUVLPDa@KVBYMOjjYOtIQSKKib0viBS3zh86OB9kFEIHqPfgkBHR@n0OwFZDBw7A1rgDiqKHuBeEZQXEwD8aIHtm69zhTbd3QOu/bCN02DFpFJsTaeLlRkVqsvEdrngxPWlZ57M8dHmK6dVtm4J4BI9ayjud4AazmgVVHniiuG8G96oBpAzMpolLDWIbmzOghg2@A7yv3GubTd9jSlHV2Rlu9rEcm6uvb3VMh29pGm/FobrHcqieoCh2W9uhXvgGv0CZKiDe1TCZjjDcnpAKrfuGg5A7t2I0xZ5Hulsk2FJ2VwJ2biXgV0EDiLSJkU6deio6qoho3KaoyornQo3EedsPUXiozo1B3ZoIENwv98Z@904VRE5OjJOCfYeUOigivIovydcsm24f2jix1S6e7UAuWG@7Pd/mZahM5mB8OxBAY8cGsb0uliZioxsBp2J0XCcSaQ1q8ZxYa1Ap7xMr1Xi@SB6yr6Cth9cT0T46TI5Zcy@tyNpZEheRriycfgFBmF@thr0NXZUp5E9pzDs@0HV3uWJpb@dc@/A6icrVOVvgFwoFmwj59XhdjAuaB63z0QbEPspdoqUFGvq9QQ1Diz11gltiKw@QwTiwbcO47nG1EPrx7cO33fFsybQ7Ob5/X@ShNORMnCMPvLYy5m5JVg6iTFKYChN7PSK8ExILvF4JXJKEM@TXj/GgCJZCASjiIB@hiy0nNeMLFhLkrjZoAmcRd9@I4g7xq6xEWycCQZIeJVoeqVfKTjFRUlPjnSMsQk4lYNHJADNejTPef0L91S10e4vRAf@@P7rcwtTx7uGTsO0txPZJadMS83HxbimC6/5oPyxAyzu3Xwkt5D05HzHvJG9jC2t6WDmTy7Fwd@ziGF/fKjtqe4AG@16cQQmRRmIbOLREHWhDVHgANYpmLBCdnu3tn5wwmY9PICzwPRwyNAQbRNxL/OIAvnvWdojZ6aHQFA6WQ@EpcJnYuhYe@VjQmGcSbw6rEDJIUtAjZBaT1/QR1xM9C4kQtJueGGJAucnUXQc8yCsLxDeo/hKYV2wshoUZlGZmM8Y7H9uLbuoWdEty2Ti6J592TPO@Gy/c6Y@iiKKbf8wWnhSZXX4vuXycD@LhApb1dkAZboAkjXdO6uwUIu4BoK5PluCCYgmKFDfNcwE7FtAOd3ilJyXsv3uFoorEhXAuC0fYuhCORdK4fLwciDm08xC7ARO3dApPvkMZPAIWTy5b0QJVx52eMtkFgZCJV8E8jtYKCF65KYS3RyrjfrIYCuTRtrZMqSkHqazg7KzAXZgP9BnubV6fZg/TUQG3XRiV9vcTFe8lJmIKaD4zM4EnYF7PZlfvwj2diyC49nfFzfuQaf7pd3swvh@j9EYeTe9DzT18ngz8xxVgAen4VvmgwUwFBFFnRp8ykXfqjKLpg7TweSFIDCoYrbfx4pvJWFU2nErbbOy8R4piJ5BbeYg04TCjvNXcov7N4uiQId8Z39Knx8cbGwLhHsGbX4aH6yI6QyJOeEx00s3q9x0C48eSui4eH6PTSAvPzNGhOb6hlWcGPWmZLZqBpjhkxLfVJoMpBoqEZhV1vCgLJ/UK07N6mlGI5vDg8Ok@WyG9V82JKUi5L6sRlrNkO4sSQKyXpiOw16CjeJ95efhBGpIBSiATHcpTiDbqnWkjioCwXCbN7WLbp2CpxnShN7266aACi6RMd8w@hIA0@bp/dKDOmlBPFybCQ@K8nqNAqKSs6TIFBTecx0VMkyh4aaJ7pJ@SUHO52CC54FpNM2Xk0uubEuXOSfrJbnmzklypF2UGfa7pdL1B/6px0XLbl03WYb03tWF99O4tY9k1hkd8Mw@5hj9jvYinWxWGNwHl2GaaKqxI4CPSVnguM0aaPPCsdpyNh9@FJVQ@Bw@NlfN4AmKqlrKVblAL8aScX@yW1ytFp5gudMtOpYBn9fxE0U8YCQUdHkLnCayFL8iX/Qp2pb@MzrZaziXrD2ojGCWFZz8Ynf3A/h1nuMSebZovp23G0gPcrIZnSHTHulLCK4OxZkoo/0gP6BCPgae9aboYZ1saNqQAqJ8EYdUb0nukSg/S@qDnu@QjItKwCrH39nvpQXDqKE0TBgBStitBcrYIzxhGwXUf7jriu6E1g0tjBh51VCMoyhiSuJ18Lst4BBATKo5elSuSp1tmvY2JwMvh3lMwtrXFb42@AW@apMOdGmafDj6kK2jE9Q349GgxAaMgwdyj4xsSZB/tBhq4C01B@XTehTa6SyQIog9u42bXdByJwm8BATjhH3CRShczmEKwAjmRH/WjuQPUkTY5rsdVBDwFyQvlAWYWcfP4imPktOObaITRCjKB@4MrJCenFTwiB5pBtlvZCOFVDk4koWVoYfOQllSk5FXCT2ccTIkE04JgAXCEFA/upAZOZMHo55kFzWfEdq1OBxLNafFgTA400nFcEX8ijN8rY5yVMPHcX7vlr03469yfJ2oMpUP/PQbKR4Hk2PUY7obJY7DkrbiKjGQTHUq6roPEMYYtLIL1dN@t2mPgUliUvFaGHlsTHlrE59WM0uc@SxNhwgoe@pe5v6jfGVHyYSonYB9Pxo9fSRSQRXtjxVaSqVqqO3bnEe@cQh@sZjLDa8h5cCxvqna8UYojk4KdgICG0/jUbEvFMZaEEXAcajNyaeuxrAth4pEynQx@6PBWw5rRRiJUojgTRLghnS@EeMh7KYKCcGJFY0HLLQWBRyLwKIIWoZaCaPmhxVsNHLI23cSLeIzxPb6Cxj6ZuAAuNtvzAU/5kGeeH0aeJBAx3SV5NpkmuQke@@COIlMLepFx3KNpjLOZxPPIJG8Yp8WPTDdxlnsp5BNRRhFwilt0D30EpccARlB95xUhet5Iv0ytSJ@bIEL3OtaQbeMowqTTVNLEeXTf8nwP9RehmkYYnvd6HVxUJMHuik48C90cmSyupowxRpbRdOkQN@5w@CSaxPlxCKSzI8R8hfs/xh7eoNXid44z1FwErBUnVGxfl7adEZ@vgDazmuGnwi028PiiKAzmW9FE8JLjrYfuScebuHUJZDEPpByJZ7XJ27eYLsdjIaiRCrq0vCR9Z2DXL3Y/x@XaDSO9akRIdilWe9P66tr4oBQQKfDIpEFczRprkhRZ@q3zpV8NESbZU@zov4K6aV3ixajSNvQYBOiBcOpZ/UuroUvSiRWu8SJerMq48IjHpt1Bv87nbkC2wgtV8bSvl@SrXVDD8Iv9M18NrtNSWFLCNanxYjJdIt9AAgYHSpouLv7SegSe6uf0wEBdyweirKhsMkm0tCzSQrJLF@eZgBqmuBtdLD2EZHBc365DydBEldQBVHyVYxwZv/45khKIr94x8ZCvPisBePplTIEgAcFK0aI0SGJN/JPSEFz6Hiyhm0HJpID7udRWoLlbfRu475jAVCoULJJ2KOCzJ4en7PTo4Ozl9sk@A/PxydFXh3v7e2znG1rCxnVw0mPKnhw9Be4SLpbzRfEjcJC3TyGkTB7S9vNv2P7Xxyf7p6fs6IQdPjt@egjYAP3J9vOzw/3TJDt8vvv0xR4trgMG9vzojD09fHZ4BmBnR0mKNQgmjcOxowP2bP9k9wlYt3cOnx6efUMxHhyePcfIcNF@mx1vn5wd7r54un3Cjl@cHB@d7jPMmLR3eLr7dPvw2f6eDvFDnGz/q/3nZ@z0yfbTp1MZPXr5fP@E0R6ASC539iGV2zswVMWYKJ97hyf7u2eYobFpF4gHCXyaZKfH@7uHaNj/eh@ys33yTVIgPd3/zgsAAk@2t/1s@3PInKTcQRUol90XJ/vPMNFAidMXO6dnh2cvzvbZ50dHe0Tr0/2Trw53908LTHp6dEoEe3G6n2R4Rw1FDTiAWuAP5p0Xp4dEt8PnZ9BnvDjG7QwqFPJLIAykchuC7hGBcZcD5haIdHTyDWJFOlABJNnLJ/vgfoI0JWptIxVww8TuWRQMIgQinkWzyZ7vf/708PP957v76H2EaF4enu6rUGCHpwhwiPstvoGqA5G@oFxjOUG6uBEqqxTU3CQVJzs8YNt7Xx1iygU01IDTQ1FbiGy7TwTNoS2npMhkie3i3IDZjU6gNG87XVqomvD2zMvsuZhQwdHu0d4@SHxcf5Y8dn8BnU5uSvFR1A86mtATrBMKZhpWbdCq2k7TxaOiYTA@v9H1WknU2q/C6JydSwsubhDTKBQgFqtWv9quwjj3tFpVk/cJOZGMu0KISe5FUKrIY8flyhtwfief52TfmiBU6aFYxqRteLi8gJCc@A/5xjaza6kslWpYIhiewUfEwQyRxxdF2rhQApyRjjKiHvtxlDQBQXZb1AYKqATo9XoVZ0Fx3yMBuR68nPdjC@8bIg7AnPmsViqFY1hKhv3OCqLhkZBmA3oJxQJ2k6LUPcu6aCnpaHQ45NdbrttQVDUIQ7A@DANbinpH8JrVmgquTYenxNKistCB7gXDbpJgwtVlQTImykXvU84UfFV9@qhBarjqBpwTpahoKlrMTSoPeXDcb5RkQkMFHp6gQkaR79n214cvcTCXzqwVptyfhO68beFuQNSqCv1dmcJV6POkwgGggZFKDSCJLRRdpFKRMMFukhD4CgDbCHRlN3BfD3TVbYu6dSAJyLEDsxONEzvjvj2Mph7Y8Ocn2892XhwcAOfE1K7lshvrBSlUkvV1kn@/wXhIoyjpCOtBNw5iGnlFWskuyD3UUv6/9p5tu20jyWfzK2DQFgGKd91NQbHky8bZXGZjTzJZSaFAEqSYUCRCgBZpRXvO7sP@wH7Afso@7KfMh@zWrRsNELSUOJNk5iTnxAKBvlRXV1dXddfFCBCdkD8RcL2OBTEEt5o0eonhGrRVRtpOCfkYDjfCpA4TNMCzA8SDbVEcjYcFRa@5K1MIwEkN1cXRXPkLkvB9EJWIBsRUZbykWVvgP9i2Xv5qiesBCQEJiVE8VqBcUC6I79kvlSEo6TYUZgeL1GxFxxx0TeOATrrIOhZ9Z@mX0LYxixEbKuJ6pWmnmgDEwywUlrKamPDK/hOFC5FzXor1BW/@IvQGj99IODoKTudH8XH8GtD4UtfE4@jkzFkGfSotnx95MEUbG7qnQwsP810BitaenBrr@B7GaiBQztFk0LMyDbd1OJBsl2Tf@rTkWjdMqRiDA9tpC8XKb6DcvOFIK20VBkR@q@ASFrelY5Uw1q51HwVV5BsdjkKhM4WmD8IHtf8b4iSn/UNQOKH1BFtGyL57YZJaZVyB9kpIGV2r@wTjEiPBpvnqm6SZW3NiLvXA5JJmwd4zgAKZnaV68Q0FKRw4OQhAIsdzDXP9aoOzSx80p6e2K9XxOmTSuwodS/YKtVWstHteIZmroi5Q8IdruXzQZHT3KVS0nrKNXCwKF3Cx7tJ6HNncxmbTVbE76mU69NCrnEjzkg1Rs@TUkKWlFr@ESTJ2mb6OdgSi6O3aG7myZUSxTDF8udVy22Z0S3PAgjbo8wgBzR03WuCzKW46WiLHA39DEewwEjXqzLgVSbi5LhldjgNs53GfTkYw32R8jdvFmFunMHtJa5bzmIxCsJPEwjCJEYjM160B1mmTvdbQ0zEl0quG/s8TjrQe8BGXKlHjYB4CoekaX7M@85cI8/h@47aTzjcRrUfp/l9NKPRgL@adMpxGpLlDL6jpP44SjCgzHNiHEiyJ/aWtaHR0XR0t4A/1VZWRqyCOoDNQgMk8of92rUJA8SXTN6SWfTbRh0hPeCPzHivxBZ947eqnb/BJzpk9GBQAB2/wOlXEIAQZ5Sa8wltdbQQfxob7ehTM@uaxHOymfT/EEyASv6cT2nbV6ZVEkOv5cRQsQQrt1UeLOrXRcT6ZXk46z6ZjfziajnzQFTCG9oIXID4u6RHjfw5n0@uIMpHQh75RqL9MnjmCCUf0wt/6aqxtRHmK4iB0zBvxeLY8vuRABHR4i2ZmluaZFEQ1zIbb0nW2d5JKhbSHI1l8Nd322rpbzbzKfHmMDciyOspc1rOXYkyuL4Z7Y3ulQPd9BQwYu1bV8t01NmEpiA8ARXQTkIJYAbNyA24OArWDtRCf9heVPoWzm2Eon@B5gLk8IodeV3xMEgic/iO8lH5iNfcbRlU@yF9gSDt8WK5Hd2vvN4YeAPgA8JtbedSSRwgU0Heg4vlELDNLXEqAhQzQ0KyygpoAKMnT2WgIiu041WhnkW01/Xm5DhtkZAJbs0RsW6FKXJEOCN@YrMrpAMvpLF3rxx@tklVyKTIE7ojHsdNYT7DBXRaatPjxHpEPb5AxPZOWHQPodajqAZYwQ1zGgNMEmaPw3r1iWq37zloGgV6eUZORIcCx1X5JPg4i8@DNynQGzNjOYE@sDUpRPA1L98TeWt6RG@QrD9c9173T1JSJzVtstsp9Qq23xMdlu5CFJ0M0aYyRURPQEKpQ9KzJPIvEhdfB9eZ1lnfgYR3OEhMdvano@e7z2sdN8S3ajKqNRi8pgh3jXbb1@9MODLyznoNImyzid4hjdJBldJb8aDSVQZPG0v0xRNQnsGfw0QfMYb99wJ05P2uRmrXHUtEz1adUvETEJ4b6RrdA4EvhAO//MRAZX5FoJsVRzYMnGNiVbpOa1S7Gq8UP3CA6qwTV5CyETxGTycrQEcWTHzgdNFhpIieCpyPzkl2HidcIozjucsAgl@6dZbV53uaWFrolkGWp1PtaUh7N8PO0s6BWVlABSzwHFXpEK7zp8v6j@tCxQDlogWvTZ7ElbVRwMK61CdDAP@anzgJl4KQrqZlaUemF0CHWAGsB1JDhOGDtCaW/0YwpHi/YZRmBaM@vHfyzKTUwAPRuQ2Mbqyz6SyziCrp5tblW9YirJATFvxH9shRZ1CV1CRoIGGKo7zWhBYyQSdDjwTQFdzEpLwWozBFU9Jq4LOElBdhMTApzviNSpcD2jlGikVfiwGyjmtsICBb5ZRJAQGbJL5K0AhtdLixGib388SQlQCBWtM8Yh6mQWUnjUM8cIxAeCVrNUU6bVqUhFEwft3fc1EdN3/T1oGF8bWS/An40hKfVZvbrfiP1NdVtq5WumqoJ@HDNXlMfARWuCbDmCh/2Hzk/mNGztVmioWSkpAwxBZ6gKnWNelvtu8g6JLdfJWOo9kzfY6V@dTgpRyq@9/tjeVsSKb794YNVtpEKEAkuT4HPlDeFw/ogCaw27vQ4KlR0VSg37QGvVNrpwPrqzcuXqbii3aUydbkKZjuNRgNpuGuGUVdWvHh@MZrW06Xrg/l4XA@vP5l91a0T68fky@No@kQp0AHMCKyJqDadDTmVAMIARbF0VTwlUdWfDwZmzH68JMO5g1njkuJub9H@M9JmF1@9oQMealL21wscII7vwtKL79pnOVNaUTchUBuNUt/a6gIH0IMvBmgJrC9LqDHky8qeBrYt1zu6wQ0EU2HQZFEgXPcmMZC1Pw7G42nF@no6G/fRFf3BbbbCy5dmhQYXwUsuch@dRxTwtGIFb0djw3EVi5ikjs2pfUklJlARxjHK@pfB8MUidOzTb23YVWDImzjMTYx0XLHsoe1K2PF7NMt0CGDfq/SVHzo9wlO2MOz0soCTJ4Boq1nJVX1SRVxKMSI4u7s0IjUf3BpFA4ChuyQKqKjoNL00kjXFNXLts0VzgDhscBsCEwb1uF8N9GX67bji23gwuB9TpIDyPLG/OkOkE2lagbL8AJ8Yj/mfq7CsX2YiVrB8g2kfVvkOVuhghULhcc/74do5Pj62HoWbm9bx8Qk8VKvW8cmx9RxfnJxYz@H3Cf7e8Fo7O23muc/dG3h5ol7eWifQBh1wbvYuZ8/hJ3zz0DEJ7YVxih/VvUeV9qOOd3jUjuqnxyfoNw5Pf/33//zrf/xX/Vh@/Df@OKEfp9/qQrVarf6od/No47aNv0@fn5cedU8fheelYRupDNn9n2eRP/YNA8Zar3CHk05/POquc9zRFhyjiKwF0WLPgX88DzSwH3/kp7M4eZwljxiWM6nuj8NLn6pb1MKRVzoubWzA06FX@tcSnZ3Ie1@/fwfvLRd5OfntE2ox9Yx1/PrZq1dm5Gvk@iS9DwIM04KpE@XaZDSJRjCoi6LKOVc9tWo167xqXWjw0NSgwwXTILKaycD8mwCpRkd2IXR/KmoDXozS0TefyPM9yVU0JPlOHZ1z/i1fNJXH/Sd8qUNtbALDw/JtNpcW10scPoCLtzBe9bS5u3NeLRaLBZ2Tq9MjNke9hdSXztGkrnHpDoY9gUJYMjB2zveOuIAGERnFImVs2uhxZjFngqo1aUyscBdLhjyP5000kIJmc3zCzf78KGOhwkdZsKxoTo4AKBss73ulBACQh9chMS6Lk81GYdAbDZb62h2TIiS9w16JXltla7DitGXZs64t43o4SBoEhKAUQOFisNFsg4y8KZQdEbfjMarfIG6sEtWFxJ@2tmmCtVFKOB0vh2PozCFznugauBNg3pXJGk@UNxf2wDW7wQBznfOK5glLzEkR7m6ARxGTHiiYfUxRNMawUCzw8RUkBUSE9YASjqQoG6A3gjOesBHLdACPsOGjIxenYyMy3MQtVQgKlVpUjlWKM@ED5dB1rZBLIlbhd3IBTORBR5CkD0uutdRVYOhKTXx7KJQWYnY5VKQlPKUrK8mmtaIvYEGqvMILMrwcA6RgyRqlswLWsLQuxpMLPX6@UoswIx7dn3HCOeqmxXfkwLF0N8pjm7pjc3SbD1cp@dXEjwW94TSKRl1AVrxU00RR@Nh@fQatnpUK3JlQC17UIYLxVTnUK8ocnyKlYBGSizjD@wCPdieKClIF8VoR78T4briYuimeTCdVYrndIB712IiPe3@oeHGI17RkvU@Are8IlAe@qFQTTD2cqQA3ckdJU520Q3hCe3lc/5da9PYJZ3LMKyxafBcAIE0cenbOEiQlLWpKoAbSSBEYyQRZMPggRZjjYDiKU3UqEgSALZ95FLcK9bjILxBgE7sZzKKtPq3KrrHPXAi@lXkAMl71DRjtviv@t3m0pwaDuxrnPtQ1eUjk0rW/Sh@aHylwTKhhBQP6cPlW0jNEmyvudRTHDKNJ9tOkaiWz8N4eqHEBkflFmXxMqAHhFlmcVE8BG60MNoCdZpZBwoUbqeYNAkbiNndy4lEZ9PJ0sUiwwrwVvShIkQhuC9qr5OZv3W9qKrszdJGFxQelkA5gj07MHHQoh2yTuSvwOlCCusRnA9Y4m2NQNDafkB0Fo6iMeJEanWo4Ml2pocsMV0lSCilEB/w8LZlzmamqxpvUPk/XrpbYq@hG@RY5hqQTuuJyJF8fSCr63R3VLjsN0dUb/bpV3k3iHKRtJtTsCMppe/UHiB60wqA0P3pybvNIQ@nwisurMYtkAcJlqnFqi65opJxpiZKDJLZVOJ7H01fxLy/TU3hjuevTLynjJ8gFPojBIiL4bl2e4BEtYN1fSi1APjACRsA2VH4UwHOhwJKHaJj2Z9HwZLpwGpUz@8yuNHcPXJv0ZC2HFXsRaEbFXsABuzBroOieFBiQzrXfBszCZ91Rvx9MVDhQqCq96U8dafYUj/NvNLuLOMmqTUw8sA1eHlVhEumF4Jqew5k/vPLp8fPpm5m/fAWbEP38YsLz@Rrb@xI2I0wLRF@@5DV63AdRw75FPTmhiXsNkVyWfJB8ejGJBhwMzhAXchAQrCCA@9Tjj9KDNdBgjp/PLrT0TPsmTOoFSygRG/Je8MXJRYFzzl5hUtQOvwPadIyktPJInzKZkkVGwA/Kxsx4yzVY1B/jTU8wSd1DqOi1QnicuZhrVawxEGhDqVzvH8qUbXIvNPTRhSg2ce@yczUfxyMZ2cqw1LiwUjb9LqmTKmPymhS8dGSYxZ0xDmz3dASrNNFliFElWBAlTLVi6I8K3TR@OnZMhAZRVTjyRGub6KNx237P3LB0f6RUDQwMYVzYKOUUx1kw1A2o3S4k@6ylR/0wpXwgHIAUBKMcUu5jYs235hzjDGPoCmImenJ/DZ3971nJ5Td025BgSeml6P0KIgPzsETXJ8v2itWQS2xDqwVK4eTX06tANFtRJwzl1UhcxvEcf3OF9Q7NLSX9GahSlsOm7PIwtdBSwqEy2TTQqYUY2pnNWaCxmsKIKUkQywnFN5/xLC3dsmN0LttgpQRKMsxZIVtJTHqkOewNmljZPCtajFj55CrpTUtAVBRoqq@YquxuycYmSa/xVC/ZwRSsaZnSFNmtZANNZNYcJVyTwZ2IClYR1fx5iGK48vDEX34xNKURkMbSbaGQR76adYhplrnWtRfLCl8ixD3UgnCmjRxBtzvGuHUJYNnmMGm8SPYHShguW8dDYItpWZgtrP3kHWs9rEBGGa9lfRDHVvHzGcZ1LYJ0VYD/McYucKkrPNBJnYCAyFov6ELko4TYIHzr0wjxmrfqRbcgNkP1Imeqae41XerkHj2hE@gHiPfMBvEqZrDigIUbCokcZasjTmx373601605lk6NL/dIGjhycijN7LkchmhMftcpdb0o0RQcC5q3XOtnHlDTWUmL9yA856kXCw8ABJY0MKwbdEa1N@WANwpgGDooJB/nJmZYrB@qg@7f0/m3wrGyVRAK0AJCQ0kHKJ9RFmKeYJEQyJmSFmjpcVQCVGtXjtxeElGNxEVCbYqS1Q7elK0690BIzwrt0pGVJPGcxcapYu6pqTohsoq51SwHo1ziaQZdHQU9PAjXp1SRa5wHy7FDHdqWpNAAFjvr6SZT7MoczsaGJbDRkXVGxshV9FOIYjhSyDibMHPOki4wIXxJiJctBZaJlvrC3PMHLiAlktW5kS@IIHtN5JDkhKae4H0@0ZjPxw5VfR9@yBlimnFyIZwQR9XhRxJoCj8VoVl83kGkdKD390OlP2km7kuqkjp6HS3yXrzX5L3Y3HuWUR1PG3D3wb@jHvuaknNjsv9YZdMB@AHvv3RMAf8wgZK/Qqwd2YHbR7Er6a4fJHpdLYo7nLlbs1/U48Tkrt@H7RiYLXk2VUBPjMkGyTLwrAxsycn9J22YSknn7oUVgoqJoGQ1M6md6GUWKWaG@qs84wlTA3ElfgDNkXkReRPi1dW0x77psEHh9wF5ppNe22S1CBUirniKP8XF78GAI@UNZCXzCKxyR7qVMQg8NAiWsU5mfnwvESu5kmODfZ28PkuHUa1gvfrpItl95LLyveWyYpnOtMuJeFYuhiBbbP3MNn5dOS05oIV2bA25jQuVDvBJ5QAUwwSN0cI4OcwXrmVeuf18se8P8eX3ujGUf/fiS1mjv5cWYsqJENPLFWKSAlKrhwdvVE@XJ/YAy3ZCGnJZxB7ub5ruD9aN6m@a2x8nA7eSclJ5St3i65xu4@up1NCEKh3S@WNuR8hreU1f2LK2LyxndUHzfCfb8NYf2/A/9jZc17jAgJd37DTG1P8x9/8Ic48hFMf7jf1G5xe799XvbJOw7Mx9q2XZD63m0Ud7Z4vnjbPFwfYXPxTj4lGr/vUM/sbFH4q7@0V@hAf4taV@vS0eFQ@x2O5tcVn3PA8epZXjl9DK0Se6TSy1PIR/jnZUu7vL4lHVo@o/Fo924aHZagEkZ4sXB2eL/Qb@b7d/T@KHebuihY91rYYUV0U2BL4LFBN5UsunUdLkM2N3eIUkoNTx9AEp7vzQaJUARuOZRWu/IbIKEBDHf3gbSAqoqwBTd@njKYphElMcDfa4UPEfxFaPK8EK0F248Ie6oN1eRK8k5oQKN4FSQgK0dfG4totX1xcShkIDoANPkJjJptygXjjUMYbYwr9HjY9sHZjiiS1xK2zT4l/uNmVX3Jdd8f@KVriML6eTVk5g9aL1DKYrDqzvIoYlmozCMIhZ4h8GkwC2ZDxMH01R0MFMbz3Mizcefc/mf09U41aPGup8F3XYN4cbqoVLy370FFbW6Iq0onewKtUz3o/tbqtfwLgxZxj6ySjvmuEovpx3KSb@m9nyVfwFRaKoY1ztmKNS1EGW69avfDQcoEjyEZAYlAB2MJtP6pRbDAQ29JXB8O9X/vcAGuYzhaH1O1AMD/u/dyh5aBSE5OKyGAxsytQTjPuvg9Cf@Rw1Da3m5/4weIWBYWAyoksblaei9Tk518RmdFytLBHGQQ6XlExVjmBFvD8qKfdPQq1lobsxZYyx0U9dmBDxbrtGXhNQy2bXAspSPZhO46Q8e43rCvQzXYNigsEksWsIXg4mIwJujuPfVEBsWpa8IDiSn9Jp8oI6Imhm1ggzOeCogsn8imhHZ1Y9bT45l7hpXtPIcE0Wr/tPJKu5bSNCcZrksLm5j1/mbHtJ95IFCR2gxwGCNUMCBXlC5nRbeAWaQhRNu99R3B/kSrAgkf5q6pssezKjh0c87J4EQ594xXV3FFOB/iiiAlizPnwHsjujqJIi1e58GNV4LZBjxSiK5sHO3v42AUQ7viran/ZSRVt1aHnmz5Z1Au4yvhrrURzEl9Y4eBuMxXqFwKaIsrwoic4wqZY/H5NZy65LpAOoTI0UsOAcVPjd8xcvPz1@8@J5BcSUHSwekVuSLusYyOXPm/R9MMZIDUxGWIWXb627u81E7kSV0lM8kWPQn5po3zQBVg1EUQ33gFHolDyqJnYW3LAVoto@GVb0dfj1dPa9DlyMyw1BmVO2A1shV638YhFduiLsq4gkmApsAHVwYMpzezYGxrNSaC2vAAwId@vEQJFj5J9Iufbhw2pVr6kn9FQFxlqtHvEhi/1sPALFs/TlfJLitiVaO75VAiaH1//M2h6WiC/U7LZ16aEe3@55jbb223vrzN0bnRV5gFA4jLg305Olmj9nLp5pNiDEJStn5TL5v/9Tctu3SRCdsRO7GP3feuep4MU1ZuovOF2qU4p6MFkxVHtXi4NF/IyjTXpxW1foTvtLSXv/DLTqvvPO7CN03BvYqzc3e5635d5Al7MQo1CGwAyDN9Ci28Z3g9Q77SJWPzubYA7kMrru/eWzTz@GKUc7sSCKT789Lz@qV0ol123jEHyP/Puef/HZn/CUf@bW6LT/5Wx6JXiZ@bqTGsz2VXTaOCfoKzYOrY6rEDjnMIhl9NHJ8o0//BykJafkAwrQLIkc42BSRoe@@Je10TYJZS7MD2LiyLPTk2u7N0OPSl3OgkGbzypuI@@tM3TbMfy5NLvYgS68Votaj6GSh1ZNGayPJrBbf/zms0@90qFvYatezqoobXY1cQChEME4@OoYMyKlSAe4ClFVzN56RDDw32bJPkqP5bDuH5Xat7dr4fmUY7qC8FNKCLjvzCtCcTNvdUrbs4QKlmHg4Qve2v7pxRu7AnUxBAu@nOD2tiSmxU6snuqDyQ05BW2By9dYxvO2NzboHVaZR57XajRcjIhyC61FmMIcmuWFNWvfznyv72hE@uEoJ2FPq9aqsyNLVG/utho7ex9NZ7BFeJgTfSMCFuKh1vJ2FC83QDYMPJX8ZwPkZNhNvYfb5f0vRif/8peD17vPnV73k6Zdsb@LyGx/FpoAzPzrGotFwGNnEu@VgEDPxZ5fD/3vp/XtfqMHkmdzrx/s7QT7ja393k6wddA9ODjoDbb3u/2DPX9vp9etY7xxqlK7Gk1ASrKZ/LHbwf26XSeY7bcaB4NBs7m71985GBy0Gltb2939nX5je3uw3/S3tnb7rf3uQff9UlsCTwEYrOK7uHdkOfDj9cJdYYW3S233/wE)

I tested this answer in Google Chrome 75 with disabled JavaScript.
JS can be disabled for all pages at chrome://settings/content/javascript or
for one page in DevTools: F12, Ctrl+Shift+P, j → Disable JavaScript (JS will be disabled as long as DevTools is open).
Quick Javascript Switcher extension doesn't work with local files. Command line option `--disable-javascript` is [no longer available](https://superuser.com/a/1114739).

Main code is on line 149:

```html
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}</style>
```

When JavaScript is disabled, `<style>` hides `body` and inserts pseudo-element with content `258` after last `html` child, that is, after `body`.
When JavaScript is enabled, `<style>` is vanished with its parent `<wr#>`, see previous answer.

Comment: HTML was always something I wanted to try because I knew browsers are so forgiving, but I didn't think to use Javascript or CSS to display stuff

Comment: @Potato44 That [mauke polyglot](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly) turned out to be very useful – it inspired addition of Haskell and HTML, which have so many variants. Maybe Wheat Wizard got the idea of adding different Haskell flavors from that polyglot as well.

Answer (score 2):

## 259. HTML+JavaScript (Firefox), 12030 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWwww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger=='undefined'?257:259</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dint 22 8 $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50) );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=  (^);instance Num(  );(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPkB3ua97CaHZN@@d0A0ugAUgGoCVWhUgQSazY6Z8casxlJ45fGsYzRa645kyyutHWGtY72Sw1I4Qnp1KPykH9Dyy4ZiQ/MPZs85mVUogADIHkkRCxKorMyTJzNPnjx58utkzXDbv/xlBD/sxOmMWh3HY57peqzRt67MvsZ2R@yJYbmZ9KokIdROvzXomrbn5qQI0xmzzWt2aNetBvgxz7k0beud2YewNGO9vtPqG13mtQ0PXiyIxfbNzvvue4/VnW7XsBsuQK4ydmJAYHNQv2RGzfX6Rt2zHBuC1hh7YXeMbq1hMIAw@72@6RH6DAMU9UuKMxmyztgzp@@amHzddF0HPTcY2zK7PW9UhJcsQBh9yznaef75VORNxj43IGe9jjmcyoueYi8ts9@YiqHr7Kvzg4Np3zT7UnVsdnA3f/oqe9F3jY4xjX@N7Qw859Cb9s@wnZZpGyytbWrp6cB1tts37kTZYH3TaDStjqlZdp2prG12emafoQ9rOn2oMs/sZFPZVHVnHFOrY9zsOHAKbcH/MKPfciHQuTLBaUJN9CyzwZp9p8sM272GlPTN1Bge0W5OskMdMgiMxt64ELthMte2ej3T44FQXLNPwZAy61j2pcS576TvNAZ1y24BnAl07Q08KpMr1SFakfUED2voYBGiAgeDLJw5XTNcFy4wL@Ta7Zl1q2nVOXHMoWfaLpTX1ZgFdXdtdTqsYXYgwhh7PcFchw3ckFetY7S1uiYhcTEV1r3sMIvVez3Gg6AYkKWDVJaZXeeNxd5BeKftsmGvy1yrC8Fe3Wk2TZO9M3ttiM66DanhSAw@9d5UyYK3ZRNgbBNKt3fyDdDNQ3LaTchag9VCcJAPyjOV2LAdIF@f2UaXc0O9N6LSA5ogRtNxNPRvOKZrRz127fQvWc2sG1hsTMw1W01j0IEUrSZWB/CB5bKuA0@oRJtBtiCyh7RA3JiYNLMgmIxfvWYPGiZWr4PsAnXt1/J13wD@6LuiHj2rC9xheVGXmYZrocSCKK5pN4gzeoEsc6C04UpnVxY0PCDFoE@4XbNPrE94GZYCUBoBryrXfcsDjsBS7LAT0@iz875pxjifmm7d6CGXhpOExBxMwcOCaMSYW1vR0vFBFBiUx9CMHjBkf/X8O19IBtMKbLmah29BlvNS6fk@u1m@QDeXmcDEvb5ixFjhA3OTFxcmfId6Ldnq30qAVQKqdFjS6XlJQ@1BBlUPMpg00Iku9Sqt9TqhhNnWVB2Emg2HakBtgBBgXyWoZPVBv4/SfUxU4xIK3XHsFtATCtsf2LzK11NQBcB/DTfBzCsTeYDXkXNNFD5vA4fAP4CGJAvvcIig0OVAUxQU9dN1nc6A4CCm62F7BKpAVMR42GRfsaZhdTAKhCMqnuu@6QJzYpyB3cCa71q22dCYnw2SOn1oi1eQnAFIyQNaQzckWyhTAAwV4VBRMejjb/52o9UCPDv1utNvCHb9Cpi9Tl2jQZmFzo0hwzq20aFsAVwCU@fRIYEro2M1SMoZ9kgkQZmgVK@dQafBqKFeW9Dk2gYIWxMERN0zOZM7Aw/ymGBd45JLRItzLhS8a9SgYikBSpuKrbIne1BLdWjmxDNqd@A1s0ztlVjUTb5StnPK9tKFCZmLabGV5WSylQeG01bIC96iizjnq52JrsL1DNexGlJv5LUdO83UOpPrBadn2kp0Akc0Ee3XojENJbUSy1uFuta07IYS3QJeLELC0Vi@XqiXrVwlPxU9nCSguUY02FxNpR6TUdRQo7hKdkG50ECSfaUKVyjMcatIcgzWQt5ImGm/K@4RIdUF@dJBBgE5pLkd0@wpKU2PoZhAuJnlxoBZJZ3CIQqcsyrxaCQaDxedMEBJJwqKjfXcclBsdXpt1DeAKLbbA5nbR96tG8A9LnZqHqh0CVYjvqaeECQLycRrMwpSuwaC1OcjapK8yWF8FQWlwDBuQpMt2WyEGjIIAWjLnntHGncc1A4oT9jzgOiwMVGjBVUDkXlBdnhBeErkM1mkSxsECmKrmSyr1ixoBNjcQKYLng@VDcBX0xwGsPFGEpI9XWOEvRpXDcYNBvs0g3VBPPRHrG6izAHhY/IOBRMZUPtzQe9lTpOl1HQmM9nG7jQxr5/cUb8LQvpdcmFLwsKHGxMKGtYENbtj2K2B0QJ54dgQxajXzZ4nBBWUxPVAFE33N@Spis5Tc9vS8pPptKkT8dWjcRoo5Hntia7QQOki1HYVdDJU/fhYgDWsPogl6MmnUgeAq6nE5dcIMpGB1/KcLPgaADCZOTTrAw@kGjDwdduqt4FnMXc2l4u8E5pOHrzCqYNkV5tB0pgZvfg4LWnJwAuzMReFijV6Fw90roiqOOFBlR/2WIzZcLszEDtBFqEjCPlqSUMD3rsHZ9exnRlIgZABWgSZDOH1AJrYGSrF0HH5ahc11kBTDqoI6gykBrR84L@25/XcHPQTltce1DTglOR5f3ToHdvILEmvP7I8h7trHacGYtmF9pn0U0jWBzVrOFUg8gvq8I0rXYEC1nRZAXrutwPgOiXadEFgkv8eAoeCZBLchIL/ygBIQBoQSmm6JIoPQKicjey6Ik8wpZxgMrZdOQYOjBiQ5gtU3iaz@Qa8pnOJYOHMaEmESrr9OjnUkE6K6BGcsiU9mijaA/MoPZJl@GkaHdeEpz3odPB1YHMpp3BdIcZupEePQLQplJzV7XWsuuVVeSh7/FjoFGwJxnioNjVRZ4pBnEdiMK2BQAEY0f1waM1zzkjZVWJQkEe3Ewmb/b7T5@l67b5zzcgDwaQwUfecLkp39pIULtSgYVhr2Ti8F30pdaXGTBUi6FNJX45GtTeOZSs30aWlpWguWoQec2lpG1xb6NpGVxxc2@RSyYVwGrooRoJcGFqmGOhXid6WfczDWAWbwxB7@3dWTzHKudxqJWGUdfFM4zMGdIYeA6BVfACeaKxQQGcsJhevoaBarTlZ@j3s9c7qfasniPCFcWXwd0GFVSIDVJzTx4FBHpWXxTTpFvqgXcBgoN5W@tGLcuqicnFz0Yhf3EYTGDuWNwo1KBSkp3S1Vt8ZgBoSK6/lVL0Si5VXQfmoFaKp6IqiZFUYxsFIJPZZNhY3OLWVqAm9oXJxEQWiCvqU6@0@4Rsm0rFYQCrIByo8oGsrUe0mC@nXYpVYPApxY9EEDN0K0ShQpo5EcKnQ2JYmCHR8@iUnzF48LlHzhlEpfu90p@CHg97J6CeDd@9QdnEctYDDOgODa3k9AZA8tH1YDQOnBq1@UK3JUI5OpPG50@Sjoj38KR0dSOaQauvz44PSaYGSaRvuJegUagthk6ArA1X6DQ2kQWfQMKVZMCA2wFUf5wTnDjDxVr3OVIcRmFrnmQh1F3U2BxvIGlI8HaZ2upNFcNuQ372JMhAS8qeYi/SXup8lDj4zT0GSByCx986OJqbIupegT7C620HlW@3zAsBrcoV7NugRjDFy7JDGaDYomMBboF82grkA27FVlIX@cM4JJ8QnRACC/FDbQk3CmoBBxE1rCEPiCM6nCNUfNVbU/vccGwanpvaSpKHMQJDjbJWpzdT/T7gipdXdcesETR@cvY5RB3k/ie5CZheAECRQMjk7JJa/g3h6cEDj@PvKCKpU3bCRfg2LxqkDy20jeWEsgb1AvwlUxUEqTu4Q1Q5ZHbTcFlDaHFoeH7VCCz/DKE8NV4nhOGmHjzOQy1BHxkz5M3ekwDp1GOGboCtjKJ8uYSX7yuo7NhJZKwFqEEV5rIMp5LPIC2y0s3OY3p9P31nIgWJ3vPUQbcNYp4lbd6F12U7HaTlsBQCQNTWNM/ahjTOcMMrxjB60KOsdEWin5cBQf5IHTTOYM11fDcabBkImCV57A70Am13oMcCcMp8dfrcEaoieSaUg//5bij5BIUNYpsuInnU2BhCrAB3kG6zJ75q99qg/wU6uI@ZNPJo8pIbJZ7IMUCEhV6KFv6Oo4UbOfaCd@0EN3zWr7CUaE@DkXXhcPVH6CW2FNxsoYWTKG319UkwgvVPh4/pFwXWRnJBbwVSB2uw6npH8SgMRjT8SasiqxWQ3GV2KJlUVf2UKYukiSzbMqyRKqTHmYcmsz8Q9NM16EkOxc2O@YyZ5/MA5pLmAj00/UEz@9GkQxJwufyseR8FOuQvS5pmGTv68PTAls952mHwBQ4xwyWToINowVlaB8qAA4rgkiCZWhCTPGcCwrmF2rK7lHdKcfcfGsYtGwltDqSVC90DejBGcWCYo5HzCYdzJ4Lz6uI@yWxz@FCQ5YYUhvsZJ2jcbyZUxtmeO04dxpct0mlNIB6TvioCk4/YamjcEBDxWifp31@/nnx/vl6onO@dPC8mB2092rBrIiIZZ7cJgtgPNYc4H84YzhCXgHct2uhaUyEf57rJz6jgeVx5w4eBhnwhG9HEc7VePDndPd06/EZmjHt3qDjoG5jG3PAUQ4DgjmIVo6k7NAd3CHszFBMrF8e7xkY/lixdHhzvV/dLJ8XkIzZtBxzL0YbJ32ZpXoC8QhOlaipP@uNOYXNGhYerELIIQNjjmyjMYmzJVhV8V/XiiOCrTMABVZOweVRVngQ2c5@6ztJ7a3GzUjGzWXG/U19Y2mkaz0VhL69lMM5tJZ1Lws7G@abL3BK6q5pBmbsDFZ0VwAgnTgMzTQ9fWfA0HhqJ10FhGM/MVhC7IXD2TMTfWNo3N@ubmppHeaKwa6eyGaa5vNNdSKXNdTzVrWT27ujBzoWygajV@69IMELQ6nCygQBB@CjwmmgPPPOh616yRTqfX65nm5mq6kUmtNWqbqUy2UdM3jNqmmWqureppvVFP6zk/Ls6ogpRoQ4WhVmmDauoHqToExiS/Mw1XMa0y@svQQuAsr6KI6fnLyDhwEAFrGDAQi8g4NSv8M@jvLyHjFI3wX0f/Li4gjzVZeg08BWCWAHEdWevXfM9N9AxWkCfWVkFUCvk5K3x@JIH5Rk/dIvJrXIMOle9G18n/yms2J7zT5H2pYlfWGXuvkjdfgZ5c@xWFvRM0EzjAt0b4@Mr1THx3gmYCB/gyHB@ueM9GNxUyCzRAtk7IcIV8Jq6pgBmAAaYNwhReVR@HZSls3pK6SGtm8NxIAe5Nws1Xy6tv@GpFVSyWIzfzBnIOmtiRA/rzkYXz9s2JFiMFI/ALSfanESYnksYh6fEyCVOvZq/vyGFEXBhY9qVDA@fAVU1pegaxBCi6l527MZsw1KCfCdA7mbobwvuvbq1JPzMAsNOdnpmjAJr2FF0/dLVG8pQeOAE6KweTU7kTydfM5gBGQcmaZaP7HjB1M0uQzVrNmgcKlMDNB/5zBliOnQ5gJJrW1jTdH/bi0gnIbD4Pe354TIA1gwZxk/P/bIL43qDvQSzx/K/fa0Al3K2itjGisWDgqNrmNfFHc26Niaj4Qj@za3fc6xNhyHUfyrqBS65GJ3DMRk21r6pto9/FIZeobmBQ/AFOWMBrPOd8LsZ/zk4kx4jIk@sMzLa6rD4DmmCnlkR4YjTI7jhGg8jAh8KWSZH6WNm8GswhHxSGFB7oeeYlNGPlgo23CnjtgTfgv7g74L5qtHr4XdREBWQqY9R0E1Rko2aZCyq9b1wOGo4Kmh4VGTO2PgN2XHqarFObHeOSO6vonF18XsC@1WqBPiGe88Cu2zC2oUFp8poe9/GFaw/cnlqDyvKg4dAbNYXughT6Hf47D8QS@@cCx3yqWR36eUClB8xF7AIqHREatzSpIaJZU2TuGLURDtXbn85lmCApOCBzCvV4PLWK3V6w9hveijQ/PvaVFH9zc3ZsvpmKk2TW8CrJN1GpfAKZyiy2Vd1TsdBxWV2jo6YbIedcie5PHY9dM0Bp3katdwwXWMsT1WFeQfXRzyJ2x56pDsOu/ti1gNnH2fG3AMxbTRZiS7TqutOxXGzanXkSdHoBbpwmbmejn9CUtDWLsA3Smdy2GrhmywWn7uFS7hxGe4CU46uouE4d4hzNmUe0unON37mqRdu5Mvnv7I7u3cxcPUBiqR1iCas@s0dp1O/jVNwORD@z6Xg5M19evTPTf7IN@FMc4QHaA/natTqOy87odxFZWn2Ixn9nc3SYgpZhq7QeFHbPjiYy1WOamGWdU69Gp@V01rOtpAE/cyt/0G9inyCeD5V@gfTS9full68fObYunnPF/mWyf3lf3dHSRB8X7UPOBT3wLBEmFiXnFxBGErgTZ3bhDlJZiqkl@Xh5XgX06@1rY@Q/f4WeZR51/Z6lNyJ9G9Q/jLCZBYfX5zr4r5La2uLUGg8TT3fQbtxXiFDlXnZM6Mjo906VsnRK/8QYeir1cGHV7AzMgTlTVh3X3pi4v33BKOThmUqJYiyL2U6cEcK5zgDqnRg/PijX2Ifj20IBY3QsaOT3ajoz5V0PdPQeDrlPwHGCjrsRW/agN1G5E6M4@3Qx5do9v2U7jYlMYsinSqTs/frUhCLvmvRdOLjig0Fc2yqsplIpod@E5q8nXhYNulaDuG8s/juRMPmMUx7D4mxIP@ScncZ4KhWq3rp0VZzUfJh0Ss@bESDgzc2kbdmmN8LfeVUyS9rWHKfzKVUIQrdhof4GWiku/NxXlXd0I7EbjI3nPlycOak158168A5JjE6BejjwXsQN4anXB1WzikvW0EpbU6@L54FCE7n3pQLdPE0u8a0TnfmKp5hR0bWstrGwRXJ11qmZHYM/hutri/BtaqsL8QUqi9CTaW0L18P4Cth4RTUyJbd6IyCW1YBBTtvsmvS6YHRgNN4MXP8xF2jo4HdGsEbrjfPi9SwQFDb@Tqy2hVQpz7FhWOYZ/ZaJ45oOrooL33nC2Z9Vn0ncw67RMvm5qkXSczzVgVuH@Whw7Jw96ZHju87qEI1v/VjMCtCYLs2R6z9nInw2qkN9Drr3T9VNtfs6bVS6r6FryZmLCffoinbbadtts813AgVv85oHcKTHT8QtKgTkv9WuM5JP4V1KYcp2nE7nIZRF@cilpeM0Z@aphOe0GhD1k/COjBoEiMe9U4DQ1xOBqNOf127a5gC6LNfxnJ6p0ts80A5OFvHfeVLUX9z5VWehFs4QAEX856@K/96xactwvF6PHtVeZ@DSD0VV6XjdrKo8oGQewhWWx7cdcb41W06t3rbuy1LNNDzbukz6M0L8deHItheigsXUffTWOhYQrz/SkBsK4fAzfBzOq1IxucS7rcAxu45zbG/Q74@QEp7jMLfjXI/lw@T@iWAal68@oGNeDsTK4Ixg0gZwZ52/g2zBEohYSJzLYKSEo8KtmilQWPS5M0oT2ztDrWN1lf/M04umyk@ZCq3ffsqUqNj2QJODVmjmFvwn@GdiMXpmZ2W3By33rrjjE/YNULHwZ2ZN77TwTPNURfNKhR7IsMVjHr3TnSRu34ZnFWpuYC5cXcksXF4hOL2jGo4Fjyo8oA4Hc6fNOlbP5b9MbaZnKgx3l5DvQo1mD5tF/TTMJl8LQdd9ml7X6eMhIlAp1HrfdOs4lY4SmetPXPrYTgsks9phY2AfdmYR7q5az6z@oMdTv35utgzcXnlk4U7LzgyuAKzTi9f3If3OwHCt7wwcz5yJb3oB@z50z4yWVX86QXkfmU9RsQePPybYHr3uEv@6bbl0fsN3LJhzQibjbIt8VgV9f9ZobWq6PjgYvXhaJaQoib3fTD1k/h7xwIELBhhuzExr1ky806Nx44hciybhLY9mZsVzJlfN3gSwKPnrQbc3cMVjduq0Tyc8Rd29JH/32gKxqL4FaczaRsebPY0dmpkFnUt0kmPnPC38u1bHabHvZlMMVDTotFEpn8Fwu9BdnxgetAh7BgNT2g9cKMVJD7XPC/YWeMJcZaplW97iCR7PM2CM5D@xMLyzwVOIySP81Z58Kgb1fDZFjhZqMNC3j@odPBT/qSMBLnaBC8/o0Do6g3PzYb4XyZh7AqHfu9jmdXi8tnDRJ4ddqmMPPBV3@S/qU9YX9ik5Nsyuh1iDKd8pPXsRC3MIbX@9Tw81YSA4cDujsWvuxoMpxrNsUNbmy@JJaH80sW@SSYNT2qh5T5ydHp6eIpG/78wa8ZyMoPd58JAJOpBBd9@s48rjvWk/d56B6gZdWQ@EbvfUxC0DU7JkdkSMduTUjQ7Qp3FvMmeEdkZfMR5cGz2zBvXbGbtm62KzEO8bnjFHd6KJQxoBBq57ecXq1Mz@G5oRDLnnDWonM/TUHNIwZD7D8FaoevU6V7hxWm6ijUyv7bg9x7H5LwnhFDz0Z4uFDXQP9PPwFXcN9y9P9H4zB2mTpT2@4ttNzAY/uDevuH2z5nT4LxZhjjiwLb65wOhbpps8suzBkPyYCrrb7GEO38ab0jZwmsNtQ2O7tmCMHezuxc1qfKuwOzWSApX4ynBpyX/2mGZiJ/HDdxW1jX7dwbUz4fjElbPQkbB75HiwVZpvTahBpQxBoBn1gW9X4J6sdrq1Lv3MHZOEavrUrOGRuxqdH/WM4SwlcvLomPCcOrzlizRs@OtMOYFRT@z@jmx6yDZJcatHPyTQr2eyiZ/cc8usvzNi98jSoBXRXHLSoBHtzIY0uQkO1JyOqXpt3GOZ9Lx5AuO5dTloPGCty19AGXRNXLOeXLmZy1SO2yaOcGav0gcCt2@Krdu4SxCavu9GqavuzGVZRA//x7tfJKFjrq6v4Qn@wVBtgTi7f18AZH7Qt8XjIWx34rhe0xoe99CMk9OfJ1@wWBmIAg/eHNC1Mq8QUJ/2oMPnO1qhHV3dBo3vQBtsOuDqkAj3TNW0r1QycTT0lyv7hm9HZm4dTm8O1e/ZHXrtBuuBEKD2XHome@7J4dHxudZz9QUzh7jhb2B1cHWPsuL7QQHJNX@K@oz2qi3WN/ePd0tHO0xpgJBx7Ng90GJBtNc2aqZnJI254xwMNb3ZSt/T82dH8fGhZabstftO14yFg/fOzhKQEfbF2czgcOwD4O6mM6RwcX6HTA0FRinchDhZBn5WX5xedzXfbpY4hkdS1T8QAp5GvT7ACSDgTI0RoKIY8XgsJolYT51r1kWjPBjJpdOkl1Yvz1K@EwnZho6T4PE8vcKWDbZVYOl0isVieW6aAqgOrDMw86xp@ah3XNdq2ZAFPwdkVQgtjnCDRS4D7dzz8ZbLbPlmmEvl9FtWYHJOZpUKzzF@KJHSsEcmgU559PKyUSksR1U1uhy9sHMsFQ3AzQ6MSmeCGxOwkFl8iAwH9OXmwhyy9RVQM88tqkBvgdaK2obd6JjshU2rsVD@PrcLwo3OnOMu47/4g4Yw4kTGyrqWa3SAIGiHDTih7Vxv83R9cvV6BhqBQhzXbZxBxtTVvR0Go1uv3ua2m6C6XhycZ4VFGGH0DV5O@BxhkAvOObhQiadbPc4YPDfBSUWRcBDLLxQMmwZdG/SUhtd2NXZm0cHVQX98FEWYwrO9Pq5GNBLskDVM3NBJ55Fp8a3jOJd0Rglz8hd/wO3g0KlkcVrUT57sX4VSxMPHOhmfqdedAeTaR/LO7DsCREEiG3VvgEvdZH6N/GN4VpcM9AC3q755GkqG26jZ2zljaolF0bAbmpPIW01leef086/KqUrhA@smzf/6vWTsRhBO/kzdXHflBPNB8rfIWOHgDASPQ6NMXh7KPMHgyLYlBkbXvD7QKB1nMjy17fOY4/T8ZoOaNlnUCrhRWKpQ0E317Nup6ZJ1MmJY85rs1NDZQBtFP1nHc6GBwWuMUPNWV1hWBnz1VT3zWAYSRFs/Bri4PTM6xIw2VzDK8pC9ZySeQdXWMyl444TsoJmfbmHX3@6/Gj6Gkdw3awPainyV1tKZAhVnuVrYKpILunIHzW2VX10M0yn1YrhRqsDgQRD14mL4WSr9NVDd6UOsx0lseaXn@zfLWjH1/r1rjJgs30bz/NgIiInlm5PDk9LZ@c75izOohVtftB3ww2O@rEEuovOgbadDhsyALqjFf4L8Cd7GYhBNZcZiUvjkHoEKWsuqvMydIdE0Efue6LPiu2Yo/C6AkGlNi0lBzwBcYBCzIdWw8IMemmNjIq4wKUVcZmH/gQ0oIAwezpkhS4lUMisAsVQg1gNJxeYXdpv7PYRi92JZTLbtmSBIsSC9chDOiziTBLd/L@XuGa77dy83x7K43ASzoNwAGvj6cQ52Do9enJYmo/mdPEndwmZGHFnlwhlbGh8J@Da0yFKEiIir1wWZyRSBv4rOjFvyNL1rE4olhGO9yyMTh1L@ZWnMmECZAhqTrQgtRFEoB6jfoCIyfaIW1PRQFv0@OoTuhhcxEAIHcoDaz7gmC8wRMoqq4ccvBmIV5PKb3gkJcSGvo25Y/Un4LQ6Lhn30wOVtbk5XFfQ6LoP/UK/ku9IVNmSiO9MrTGVp@HZMuwUF9mFjed5HsWVOCHmZ510O8ovGLCFPjTcGLRjRSRFxEhV66Y7Rc31lMMKeO56ZY28HDlm78IVJoF@QHVWD256lquUWVcmKBozQQTv3@y3Cd3hwVkDtjKtmJN/DPDewsaMCIG4GVpxH9/poLpkfFOb2GDnJHWH6z@8qadLFFaa@Ai3BZVeWa9U6nL@aqON0QFJiaUTB0ZQw2TlhOx0XdJIGdN@goXjY1YJyotHxRX6GUbWZHAGe1AKVMcFkCWHdwl1TcNCVXuMg8jWPvExwhNkN4YxuLakqUK5l2b7d4BwaEqb5hhzz@gPcnViM3oniZyFHLrXtdTshwBlGMS/M5Mff/G1uCPPCA/ePhHuY2oW3XxdvTXD/hh@i6/D2z4K3NLz9mL@9SmKV3bX@N85nYMhh7oFPYM4n8p2CoWDwLShTgYIqx@r@6vCEuXU0zIsV2jWGobpCMeOPU5jVBc64oopGcJ7CuB7HeJTyV8AnwFzAJKjjoFpD6Zn9ioKG4HLJJGYc15E02iZqDvnWDbIL93aA9lBBE0uuZ9bX9CRkUr3yEZKpmhaeWuMIY7EcCEbpyuoVXtfqbGtri8lu3eiYhfU8Z5DksvFqVX4dZHQZYCU@WigziANRxjEgrCiiKctGXI9hVOzNonoUBVvD4fwGKqFCDgCJobftG7cAndMRpAJmts2hR2rTyB8FgdS2nZAhZB@RCog4brTaOd0mxyfRcPIz1Eq1cDXILxGMRv85eRbHll@xC@/CrgjrrQy47@cz@NcG9z@ZYdKVcxYa77lrS1SZtgSKpWFPzmwH55APILdMSSfTq0l9PRbiUFmggvxie38PKKGFg8Som9Ybp@fu7JUOvzg@ObtjU4ogo9NgURYtbsUvVC1RrgSOaJDvSaLuHiTPnu0e@KQM52o8i4sQ422509mcldp0Tuek/pIf@rubNgXcSUhPPRQxTQGpB7S9/S72cWgyBLjHzxzdSVWJ3dyWK1vFCztyJ/n3s@wER7QVZC5wXbhkJTg6nU3MYnAnwDneCeBq/ol2HY@z4zlHz7kcH44XHqEADu5jAQkgaUkfap7whAwc8xmgsRWXNL@UwCXRx2eJyHprkKMQ5Ll/fQE2rbHRQWFtr2247Y5Vk6ADb6AFSm4rxzcGE1jZ0dxex/KUmERTIAVUg0CIKeISg2FuqNHis0K2gglXgi0y4Ofji0nQCABf9GTgttmJ0wvNbe2bvusUtBG2P@Arkyb7YtAFuCY9Tk0UsSboJypEBkJFg6zyUTW0LGG/bxhHG4mQXhmt@ImCa91GRhnGtLY5bFgtEOBKLAEt/TMd1KrAwgAWmmz62VGQcZzCn@NZrzBJP8mM43CM3CgbmmU3zKGCdolyFdBP0T96/fIqGpPv8ADZktzzrc9NGZX0G6LhiRYxNsg41dg2g5sLpqx@bm6ibSc0lgDVAimeef0jcEL/pDS7Ro8pA7J26jKN0atyodgJ1@vHmFrkBlNsFo/TqBoeFABaM4I2yUWMwxSch1SSBagd9HXtBj7eWT1W1jWtAm5KJMaWcUZtD7pynIuKSTBKgig5QlvAumU5zBHnXo1zHsTBcInMrzE0@TkjmIx00ty@g7SgUrPi45DZqnEL5FTd3MyJ2pgUNZsM2OKulNeSgHaGCPG1VKCvOPsOVEMj9njbAS59gFh48qVp2yYQCHima0AfbAyAyfqxhH9rSWJs9JxSiPAsPhWH6SGjk8bQS9GbDq6PLyfzNDmTv4U@9fUFdqpN0a2Okv9jUkvmb5TlTmGUBEUnVlSW2wU9vroSjy/bK8qyjV3948c4p3O7DJpEVYMh0hCA1OVOLA/8DJpHYdnOLxtbynKjkF6hGPAKg7QbiPDBTWo3y8Ztcvkx9NQJ8Onzxqssu2RPM6Vp@i3kD1vIcjIBPHOD5gfpyhJMftmKxzEP2nIVM/AheXEWJ5l9cZak6aO80EaTra5oblNSNaiJOxe2cAIKb1HRINjTKNjFGYaqDzw2hb46K2yO7sET/hKPiTHamWq6YfVfngx5uGAR8i5Kps649VJu0BQIOFSAiPiaMGIxECa//GVEX2eysry9vtq5ikczqTz86PkNlmGfLV@k1yIs8sQwPBiyJ1duLvazrStmNtPrb1W1bDW1t5WTy5OTr4ej2IUSjewdv5L1NQDdYJv0fehng6XnfNinfSKRlaQUSa7ojzeSydevX4PKi59yUSv6IFolVlajlbKyITy6xY2NlcR6diVx@iRahbxAcWNKOh07Y5aVZBdWz2004Ou06QIhJcI/bHsb0wMH/DPh1x02yTncMVutQckYcX8rMsDHgSfiPvvuy5cv0fGSPuzdqYgf4RgFukiuamQilMl0Kv0Xf7J0m7g5qW79xfe7SXMJH8f4@NHtM3Sf6ZnPlpY@291dW0sA4bj75Lsn3@zs7KztJzIn5cz2mppa2vrzP1taSqe30smliuvqlWj58ms5nVqTtb/4vWj15OQ7rot1h59VpoMTf7Pw1Vkmwy7ZO/hcNhn@k/tdI@Q20F1rvsMOEpTlAgmbaDSzGj17FcX6eRfRdT0yor8qFW2J6cXtjf/2k@O3ES9STCdf9uHpRd5G1rMR7gQHvK36b1eRYmQLwdZvI6NkoVAA58Z/@/cQv/gF4MGQ0Rb8FDM@rvVRpKgWKMr7SHEdHHo6Den@P9/7nhQpDiETxeLhAUsX0yuCTfTsY/0xuWyvDQrGRUTPrh0/oVfLfHKczqS30G2bePFKG4ajKGR0PX3BROXpogqxuDr@cg/WBjfWqRNhPui4zpnPUUxwAjAI8Qh3Cw9iG@6BwRNwLy8MY2UjvpZ@Yudfhj4TL/8Qn1O84Wp96cnr/WRyqwg9PX5yuScXVdHMkmwjKzvOE5z8y7Mj4ZvHn6Gjqg6Aw/eCPFX8CAJGsoVElRPJb2V@CBu/sbBXRNCSBQ3qV4Ar4ecv/6@//Olf/oT@fkrf/yxF/P0ravmqUvQ/wEFysS/fXIhX@xl7xj@2Df/w9V/RBz3AZYu5yUjwKRbxh/7FG7noOeUnQorBC0GMo8yFY77EonSlyIdkkuWwlq6KxXB54JMMXqkYPOfkeBYq3bh8ojwgGre3l@CP/uETvOLvEvkIbwK5@1lixQWfxX2AFClHypUKb9bTJVrwOdWQ6zTxVg33KldSRAVBFY@fApcywdzwuYjf83kBX02rirekNsYakSJ/75@ixCI38KnE1dvbcnTNia47T7RX8Xxe/IOelw/e8MNdkMPKrapuvSrG42XKabkosrylskqRF4B@teqrLUAf3ypvFZw9@mpVpJdaeVUsb01GpviV4pMncSTtE0BQXK4wGFpAbdxu3RZvy1u3t1tb8L9Fv7fiCb63W3f@6TH@zIEZh1ew/i/KyeJFUrTKYgXeNWBq8NGSF8jd8AS4clmK3CDnsHKFzMIV1LK@nqmojFrICkivZE5fSa8mM8PP1ktpEAIugqdlObmCjvfYXYLCsylFcOiwyUcQm@Tx@uO3/wd@Lz5@@2/hFbKG9@9RaO0t/h29w7@3Hv6d1/Hv9C3@nb/Dv1MP/05c/HtWwz8pUmAMNLbl7VQndZXSL/VLcFgsBQpzO9XWG9DZsJTJUqPUiKW6jt4Alwl/KXBZqSZLtVjKTtm6DoHg8FjKQ1cTHi34awKWPvxZqRQiT10xSKWDXRiZU6bn@yqLXUhlFn1tgpql6VpKW7eqlcx67205WslHkhcXSa57svRansxn394yVq2Wnu9Xq0lk/otnzvH4//i4G35d@N89dp4dO10H/o@Pj59dgAArxp/E1SfwKRTjW@KxHSnmty9yKjKuz8KR5Nb2RXFVRfd6HLgyjX7xT/yMMcKzuHQhwdj85cvrPPWz@eur/HWeHMErd1QFgADjDoiVF/0z@EC8i5dJ6lGv4XNFeOkNndcQ6Lu4I/ny@gI1SBgvBP9AjvDr38O/9f@v/2cvmFKuxKAR3NxuKfSJ4V8sdnN7cyt@izFFES/KFvyhB7xjlJvbIjoJ6AZcZSVWid3ecj/4VWJbHGER09gqUuQxIEiKSJAmpct/lL/fJ6bNPxdRUJNgJK2IZcCLi2EqFcvXwCdYCzDe04pSLE97bZZruAoIo0c9RhCZtXxeX@Hu9Fo6n18TLxvZfD4r3MuKsnn3U0xt6@vrufTaWiyWz6cELIwT874TUJiuUc9jI89HYphZ3vKVFM5G0sUZUTknP36siKtWtnu92OPH@mbq/fvAq1ptWP1qFf1X37@XqzJuyylsZuA9lX3/HoRONOb0lecOXxBWVJ19li5SCptOH0q1AcFMT6bHabYN1/C8vvLO6iVk3C7pyjEydp1KOf2L6C9@/P3vX0QLuFGDfNd0RICpsMzW1vpasbi@Bu71LBRcXuY7f5RWfFOP3S4nZV5cJi9HIyJIz27EyPc2iuEsssW2i9BQXfywm9sI1R9by8SU2siM3YCP76dvbnJPtrauZOOb4q@wFGPFFSb@yuXyanxtZWPlSQXUm7sfFKr5G6MQTSajt4UbI4ezVrf5urhUAQ8yGY8fr24CMbOp/IVUre7vnO9U8T5GXJOH3o@hJ0loCddbe/1omaYYM5uVMhaschGN5vJPqNr1bIZFonkBp0ZB2rPsJpU/4rqS1cQTjUPCOvVdifSYvrEK3Sr0qlKPtkdtpFgDV5j7zGk2l8AT6o7VcDOAa3Y6/kUU106/07i2GuaSFDk52tkrnSfSoKFE0gc7e4n02YvdiI6vmfE7BrPIKnqclnb2j19AjJOj0s5Z6fPDr0ovTsDfld68M0zTMAemeV0dDK7f4mUFZtXsge/4UzXrlmu8eWP06AOjFC6cr68//vyHH3/@P3383R9//N0ffvzdn/7i25/@EL5/AN8f8@eP/91mBn9/8e0/@/2Pv/O74Pmf4fuf4Psnv/j2t77Hv/T@p/D9LyG/PxXfEBz/SoDr13/x7U9@7xff/sbP4Psvxfdnd7@/@Sezvz/9wfwvxvvJ7y@G@fG/h@8fclw@7I9/h/vh8w7873C43/jZx3/xH/j/n4s/dP7ux3/xp/gjXv7pz/78v3z8/n9Mp7N//m8@/vDHH3/wk48/@P7HH/zo4w/@cfrjb/0bPRX@@f2PP/2j//7Hf/jf//h/of8/oN8/fMj/x5/907/6P//q//6rPxbfP4HvfwDXn/zVfwRe/Zs/@jn@/@SP/uY//Rz///d/9Td/9L/@za//a3L8Nnf8v//y3/Hfv/7@D//6B//8r7//7ZzfHy78/fYB/t/@A/g8PJ8PwfOQcn2qz7e/Un7@LtQYpwI8QNdCsDRosbsjk@YrPhvmpM9YpLiCHxDK5Ww6G18BBXRlcxMkc4X8txCESdBOf/pPPv7WrwH7/wtABm//M7zBP3@BoB/RC/v664lAFqc5EDX@9dcYKAaNX4ehfgQe75OgjqeevAeIrymYf1gABun@bwQGcEyA@XCTGSAY3OTJ/X/x7T//PQoI4qL3r02gTPneYehlBH/vF/VH2O7HpQlD/whFx8eff@/j7/3jjz//7Y8//3XsHNS1zcROAvr2xdO8AJh5ABwCrj8EDgB1HDTCIH9JSoNjaQunJiU9/vo15H4JXDDmWpEyq/Am6UVy6@iGiHF4IyTDYRx/4V9a22T4Aj5D8oUni0PQbhyvC49LwwKEESjeM87QWcyC1xAnFwqAFyPxOIlqFkYzbLhLWCBmIX7KqiuFIY8YR48iYUC2kdDrVNbTcjxb2IcEC8N9hrgQeVx6Dc/XhWK2MCwiug@UBcAR34UkAQqvMY8Pix/gvUA4AV4a7n@ArGQL8XgxCz4FLGScUktUKU09Q4WjsscZlRv9GcPNlttPoMnIelbmkx9ASiag8Tc@hkZAAIfwi/iKKA79@076rmB8qKch0Yf78fBt9Kb4AgDwqiru0YOvqmJunkDwkKOKU7LwiHMMQLk4qVE@SvAgjSUuxal@4/QC6UMePu2zhaIC0WFxlpeXwbVVlFfl6jEMImG01r/MuZ7RxzVE0iRzTF7flNEbNzzxrZzLJzTaXNlfgV8d/ktLtH2ZypJfkZajOG8R5VmDtNT4qrPmRHgx/DLS2woVIU6A7DMIwe@TJ@AGGtFz7IdTDfQfl15FJBahuofGkuC/8NAK5B9qSuTxqiDFx@80n81jaFpCSyTEU6MneWjCoVGoeGrLpDIyPvChlWqmr6@xmKTQhVwxrKG6SeqY9Mxt7TpDGHQkZDmhr@PqU0xM1Jzn0thapVIuBb/fOLlc4YO@tiHBk94HeDGYuKIK@AavR9e2trD@izcqzSahE5TWdalYFAvvTJeKZ6VzAD8/Zno6pTEYsNysbaTXMmuZ9Or6emYjra@tb66tZ7KrIFnXU5l0Wt9cW9vMbm7cBtR6AsIpkVupZbaK/@jO53/4R7M@s33xIxW/ZkONZtBvpWKnwDeALuMivHyRkvM0tUW0XC6nEviXXl2FX8hnQs9sVJaWOjcqFvuCdh3e4DYHyKp0o2LH9wg@THoksUfgBR9IA5chmdg4cnicF5sE8H5PvlFA1jPAyFAPF8DJHB3U6M3NTegrRZa@@12PFYsw8FAPD6QItME285fFVauhtTW6lrMx6JsU2mJs//Crw7PD4@fa/uEZjAS@YenVlCZFbm9vm8FiDr2a7Pj4WELhByO8VR3j39bZYDCg0Bq83w4NqRf@5OErpdNqelVd1VV9Ff/vcaTx/@HwafhP4y/EWk1L/ChfB4/u@FNmm9IWN0xR9K9b12pOY6RZeHsMHiAreKOeSTdg0DG3c27/vVCIBveZRrfTmQ1g/M0tYROquOV6o45ZREQ3DcvtdYxRzobx9C3uEM0ZTcjFTZ3vrMjJ6UxWvoWoFEXaEoYhirRoXQY@ruAdcuXKlm8yoih9@PBhSPtEcoe2JzaMpNey6M8kbLyPoVd8rHNnZn3sTKHzHM17PAdGgtZnsyPc9@057Nzh@4t3zfociL22QVfq7fUdGHb@6jC7hn3Jg/YtbmcgCHpqoKFht2t57TkQL3pdPG9o9v/BMJS6NcggMgIH2IWffsdxZgFssBcnc0r5LDALhHtLyC4QgJ8efv70PPQ8L@3sPZXW2e7x8/2pR0YAZdhR6eA8eN3goX7UTIDim9LR0fSreIBoz9M8wxLLbPgOnUUMzyjIiapcZmuVvHe7rW89fqwvJ0@OcCbjpA907DhJxi4@qFtfqcVsvm8OPXvAXmyCoC2WoKoByV6/sLvchM6iZZah4cMwvwKl1nA2o2Nq1WKDmlmaZdmy9Ay3sG7q/DyW5Up0LBIvacMLGT0JDQ808CJ2nHmq4Y3ogx6b6wkP9EInNMk29FjXjg8g1QyDwfdTPxA/PBMBhFro4fE0yO9OSGcGOO6ZsJosJWmcKpvZTHZzNZ1NZDezaxl9PZNJ6OmEvpHd2IS@IqVn9fVsZlNPZNc2V9egQ4PQzOaGFAEZbzWTSdAadFmGZw7Q2nW8V2QLL2hxtHZRinDpxN4pRgyqOngfMNmEODLecOd6tEt/xSrI6TU8QrOqM8BosDqLHBzspQ4OZHkXX3A5Yi8lyw18yWRTqY1dWTYpZA863bQsOzwOBAGYx19Sqd09WR5wBGilSJbb@FJaxyGNLFv4srdzcIDpvMGXNMYHsEsewl86/ssGgNn4srpKYyJZfhugA7gdntAa5bSEL5gmhhzwkD0Ik@XP/fykUoDhlMNxDE/9su7syPIhf9nZwZAvqOAZntUv8WWHPrLchxdgQllugaPVN01blmvgRFaU5Tq46iMD/PAOF7RcY3uGLI84gZBEsjwkaKN@KYPmLvwxmadPnxptr2G2@GfU5886ZA1CrOGgdFD7/PNaq1Xrj3ZKn59iyBdfPDXejAb9WqsmotWq8HEgDoRcdkfTH8jjYbVqdGaGfAkh9lRIdVQ1MW9V4y3kSXxamEi3@gWEfAEhM@ZMhxwbfLoAWsPPbheeu0aNQvwPhdBzWKvJeWRU7IBxjhPbzKUNsiDRNep9J4/vw8ISiyrRxKi8nqrkyZ91FRa7SeVvMbyp0D2hqPWiEhi7GZWHhVQFxnQbaXHYR5EvhumMJSeWutv6Zia3ZGzr6bX4MIeGqJ1mlEVVfVvRH6@8U57HttOrazn5Yntblct6ZTutZ3PrG69WBrIcy@Hv9upG7h2oxlHQf/EnVt6obG9kQlE2NuJGMp3b2Ijlb4EgHvQ@tYFnVquKcm0al7EYZhj7dCV2Q6VlIyqplW8qw8SwwHPFRiyWHxb0PLehwFJTyJiiNNCKzwDv5IsxQtpigHK4ncqhcFZkfTMrQx6SSSUWQ8GEogSer1/6K2HBI@SYcPKPxnIqv9JTz67HNDw7UnWaVbrWjL0OQ6J@L73Eg150yNvfj0lDMjcnneNwAPsCg6EeVcNbhMmuAAyMue0pxueI9I1NSSoKbfiEX6iUF6@fP93TQEEWb2gRSDvAy@OdvoaXHnsTIdxaje91Dt2b9tTEXZZ132@PH7/WSkMY/eARk/yN@lK9Dcc4A6Wfp4EnUPJkDgHPcqNpJKvBjEIRXEZDoeSZEbumYlaLxUK10DW7PW8Ew0G@lA6F8mM/H3TZLuOweC7MPxVTLexC@VN5G60Dmvi6PIwMpWIDbR/tFnZvBjnUCm/zZsHs952@HMGzdNt2YWC7RtM8Mft4jOvwGPpsE89L1duvL0oIuAe0vrlVi31mj8tw6HISBYdyKEM3mCERUC2kbvPhXCuGWqzF8q1CGUHf48@WKssVVS2/r8DgLi8VoQXmRxGj4A5q/PrIVA3Gdev5IfjpG2v5NqsVaq@G@X6hByMRlu8AEUMjLGbkCf59B7rUqlYtDMfUWC2U0zDGSiX8UVca9@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@xDhO6WYHs3TSGWcs9wkMgUI8ebbbkS@/Dc6txkV1U@0FRY5AOLJzXamFVNfohAz3BLtPZ34X35Op0B6tuO7wFDSg/kH3QkmYyME0Dma9Y723y18Sr76tmL4xfHB@xJKpfNZadmgC@eJBJ6VI9usSegzlqnJRifvGdORv9gf8G3KkbykVwvuroWXZ2OWogMC2v@sreiF4uqvpVm28CrLAcyqqmvq6n3Rc54RQpYT0PIx1/72dpwKwvvaVAbc0DTTDxdLOor6Vik9/Hbf4uH7W5KX@0csSiaPvjbP/u99Mbf/tm/ojXW6G0e/dKrGxGARKe@vhG5uend3NzCh4dlIpUIz9PaRgzcfP1fjxSTwlvf0GMRV@VvkN1MxH0vbKEo6VQWwvaO@Zu8DtSMbEakSPbZ6/eMbcHgsdhotaw0uZLJO1PqyzkYoME/@4BTaB/UpdeF4nISGADnAzcxgj/ls1IsFldwrp5Fi3E8OJrO0JJB@TZfYXxOBgcqKzb9me4K/uH7K@6x4rrw7gfDK07XbpksU9QZDG6SyY@/9lvp9Prf/tlvXsTeV99XvwOyd3Nzc11PR34J@VhwmssfndBkBp7LQkcwqmFz7rXT6rIUoXkYxuH9MQ6OavAsM7cEg2/SFXbGROIq0NEAlVIhsBU8k5Ig5ZIOsMbykhSoYKQ89lv1BOFgK2hEFNqOdCM9wiDolFgBZJP0aIwKPLpoQqZedTuDfo/0IIXi6ZUEewxRIIVHaHRgic7SCAGn6nmWXLkblWeZ2x@hDp11TddFu0Mgf6VHEOUIuJRuI2E9A89jISS/4RxBKJ8U0ChD2hVIu8MjVMlXodJzgATjueORbNAupUd4uITUT@izmbUFAHkWkx4BAaAMikBsVdgWW42xGysez4/NFN3iDik8o274pz0kjIbYGnjEyY@cRziLmyIY9NE8DxM1XDfDnj4SjoPP5BdAMcbo9IYKCR3oejAqwEUHexUqGnv8eJyrQsFqxBiVCPGjlSY0rTS2KXMnAUDmDyk@a@TkBLPjcazsR5NsBxSPU3aB61RyjIGaeOwGX28lCf4fzLTIkVNVRQF5LICoL94q6kAyiIxk53VYRztTenojxoLM1yHvdcoUmasIxkkXw880shpT51m8lX4Z8a3wSXhrcEirF3w7fdyHgVwa4L0seJaZCwNxkIdb7EfhdOj5sYNYUBSrQ9BNqw9qNK1K@IYvlFU9htGagQ/lg3ZGpdcYblrKxPBBsRAazSMYaGpApLNExznJRpPbc2yyTUDnPHFrF1mMciVuiYFne2BfG2RliKdCO6FCOeKmm5DzybKQzc0nuTwuroDU@jDU82mTYGZLIyMc6U2mcHNgeAjcDtDFKBJlGEZFBtK41jG7kKUz02R4Pt7NJZMty2sPanQg/pkFfNU@sKDbsN2kuAEmeW1dWslzNN6oOk3QVsUBrAj7yuhYgW0aceqcTEt1LLyyHatVmThB57L0egLUvQRQdvwFwuZwshFPyaUgOMGh4LsBjw3uzCZCcZeUUezuc1VfUqoxUgvIbEgfb3m5MuwQfenzXhLjMHfk@sdj6bwWvGuByIWWyc/IRPGQTHB4SxLneAt0xlTDWeCeAuqUf6oLnaBimlcAoeoS9jEgNOv@cTNsxVDaR9QBUNuDloX2I7x@Ds9hFtCyklKHpicEvM0@Y6tpujubn0wWB4kBB1Z9YRI7hEFULIfrNaBiND7CBrkCrbPbgLAImlPh7Ifxfe5GN9lSGbM3WxLosNOhtAqMNwv/JRN6wdbBLWNB0ZcgcB1yOCMnS4ocB7RxOSZz1EH86eic2yWSJTl2F1OCIQZBasCCqsKu4XKDgsL4w/X1tUb2RwZ9SzNdtPTo4u1VyV7LAm3USXowkhZG@i28YUXcHjV2qdzSK152tj2kO8Y2H4/4U5KaeCLy7cDqm0q06UaxD7wCWdlrdelwNx67dolvDiyyfFpXaKHMFWyWriRufDbLIZup2egtImEM0QwTo0Q9AcgStfplonndyIuAK2p3gBwqy/Q90TRY33/pur7L6jUDCMejTZb@e61zWXc6DqoeMp9IHCfNS@hDjvxX8d6zhhDJNq/ZTr9vjBQKjyE08qkyIu2GjaB3pxBwQm/CbrgFHWtYHlUmog@D6NB3@WMP1sej3dLNYqTccBGGD3n4EMKHPHw4TtRPtjyscM0LvW6xOMjcaKnFh0Q0Ix/mlttdGocQZtCLmc5RIORowu8WvvUCxfbpzd@gHgs@YwBPkLkzBe2slS8qtmter1TiyRbwtEyEgBoH1OUK0fS6EbiR@p2rTs9xJ7xsNGQCnY/IN3rV24IbOK9gGYMKIsbg9LLQ3kWrq/GJEt7viwIDBlS3IBA1gB1PsWL5wNIkBQLjlOUxjXnGyiIzFVKyRJDwA62Ik54TNoyoEkKE/kGRIJsQwvyWI@z4CiHwso9XHvqwKhmaJ5OZ0UoUKDnVVLhIyVMlhXKlqn42geyolRami@KHQ1WUp4JCxbwV9R/O/tInZ78J7WJ27olheb@Ql8JNxRyieUBTNBeiKisWQvUKOUiuGB2zDx1UiauholOGZFaS/miCp4NF4GYtlVDl12O8fmj/umzLuYAVRoUCFHFU4M2StwufpJzgQTRXRBv5jCDicwECOFIzo5ki2jAcbVgocMHBhnOiXYcyOaRMDnkUDj2ck8mKiAaDpMBwIlZPBe1lgUIlAz6d95ZoG1JmrnGFBkDZG7RvAYMnP82xzCEuEDyEmjTyWb0yM/VyKNMhoTWFABnxDoIGvzYgJ00LPF0N3gIZxUnpyyj@JtiAywpgMBLBeW7DSAmYjIa6oNfLceoHoO3K8bIk67hRhf5S/CsnfE//q9/1TE1C6pOeqcTU3z@IZwUpG2qgISVDT62hQMYByw6ZdAC15NphygzlGfyT/r2QyVrHqSW7Bm4YwAtkg9siY/54gIy2Pek5nuE5a2s5PgiyiL9eCHAWMtnNxwBWy3ZgqBG2kWZxm252FE3X1Z2WbblmAu@n5Cq4Savd3MKyFNZ7hdNxJUnM@vFhKaLmDISqa7WKd5tUq4prdpqxXGCAEF815MNoVMLxLLhC8UEOCaTHPcXBy3m92P040YCgiHZu1S@V454IjEIiOwyEVR30eQhtg6rCXGc8EiTLXqga1zyF7Eu3na7TAvUOrfZh7Cn0h2PcmCGj16O8JJiBQ9RcyMwiNQelnjBiIuqXnxyVfZlWjFgQPz2JYIIYCdafpjFStj8juerc5Hg0P72zT8/vWTi/Z4vzS6Pq6TzzoXaBB35a0qvKGAMAjrOxen82EsJI7p3sTGQl8EYFikd4cBYbtCGngTndAdAdAa41gT8SwZtLpjtExr@aR//FFehHLz20@gy86ulsBPKmi/u@FLKw7vqLPwqAH8ZQ9txNLmDt/QemBbCgR7AD1BVAXyXBZaNdGGiYPRhGu3Kw5CEQ38PzuA3nDt/T3pwCD5yRp/5Vgl2m51fRfrVhdoyR2VAEZCKE1y/xKYzMSF49rOAo6EjoOXxQp0AnFQsblUWic6DcHJYxElchk8J3YDiIFXAPzXxTDg/n0w/D74hmnLIr8NlnUPij0QhZnyZj4b1Rb8Tt6XX4PQRCjvL@h9cknuK7nyBAB7GCnxgnG1skPk@VoEgP6BECWG2yyGQ5x@@2nG7vbh1@GonuLylUbihSwa/lCYu/82rcWlTjIa7weZKv5zyMJe9jugfzXIjVOLKxCNv7tC7kDmbcIVCvK2GM3GdhjTn2HZmAfjTvZs/pVaozBGoQkySdZ9G4mvSLmIRD4EN44gTSV/BEhC3Tq3KG8suGc1TixgpGIV2jF9JahA9o44AlREXfrjtlIwQl@W4Av7kN0qzPTbN@J836RJpBC5hMMgQk1SeSFLWA1bOoCjpm05sjnTEIB8nwWCS24WM7Rh@nJW6iVjRnJVj0KpoDgRw1o7mSAkI52ojm9snhRnNn5LiM5r4Ex7htRd9Hc36zQIA@vJLjCfoLEY7v9WhuT4ndSh6a3vfT1aK5oE4BZpu/EkWAFFhu0Bpxycx2RDG9vgkdGymVCYYc4yZwnEQTLgn6puCf29jmd0FAIM5ZrhAwizN9otMI9Rg8Heg2fOuLM1pyTvTmpeMD2mEzNmIO4XEYzIXjEHpQwyPRSWHEM4ahtEIBT8ggys3c7BwxfdLS/QOyI1IHDqVKnkyfqKeRPtBQKLwMwJXYpAF1Ed@vr0kUvAIflk@MPC@fd7LjJ0c5wjXW2IxsIVFfRxcUCut66nYAXvvhGqK560kgvBrNB@G1RGhDMh10OFpsw8R6Tm@SSSgUd7VZ4Tg0@8YbJXLvVDSSCqJlzgkmb1EyFAzhxh9bVJxQPMzahAjCwHKqwltZ0C@QLMagsawLaaq88UEWQjIHWrhZvzSRbfeFk@C4uElQXzGvG/Lj8iRJck2KSYisoTmCgeHx1IPBawmNFHza8NWPOcRJFQURhGIGqXD56nyC/u5w/d1XqH0iTCUwS7Ge3ZXeVa8X9rJTOe@Mk71bgRiYYPuxmcpRkMKY5DA6CGnmi3jtjoqPWzi4ks8TDbBPafs@2YIxwT10mx5bcFyoJfSvJj0v0@B5mZ5PqLsaSedK85UWDVMSeHjBg5yOi7Y4r7zgs6oYQ2gi2@h8cgX3Jys4XHmIjwrQnyI5b@V4tAzXtsZtm0xbog@KVD3HuCCn5c@gmseeIO5pKTZYhgWP4@rp/vHzo2@g093Y2IiJPno0zh@2WpxUDfpxjpn23gb9wYxhSzqBpp1x8ZpuP8erBpcubPmOLOHCGpQBvNLCZz/RxmNCloXk@VTbhXgcNkRRgety3AyMCamEqo6BXbYl6OoBQUxPWTEEEl@9BXonaLQWwzlZ4A68Hatape6rWsXNSNWq6MWwavwV7tgvI0vJgdunO9644dlrSaKDoGz/mL18unPOzp@W2MGLvS/ZN8cv2Mud5@d4kPLkxe7R4R6Db@n5WYmNZxTwg8b4cUAJdN0362a3BiI7nUqtMcK85/RGXO4oezHuf2Z02VOnbuJ61JZrdJ@0@Ytmm16RxyrBcHQkriuGjHYtz@MXWdUBHSk3DTqKhfvXGcDWYEzbxTFv12lYTQtgJRz79izT9Q8QsY4FNQjy1j@6l@BKEl4MQFuB6FIous8LL4QCeFykATSGO76AzHJ5BLOhMUG44PPJFDwvnT47YzvP99ne8fP9w/PD4@dn7OD4FF5Pvjl8/jnQ8/Ds/PRw9wUGEeCz4/3Dg8O9HfLgGUhpDI/K0g1fi7KgIThRpX6JS9x0Z2PwFp51BjDQ4Nm1QYfSXBYd2Ch9LKNjvTMb0byEV4bwg3C0JsCCC7uY@RaXMv01X9pPIL9w6dKL5RTbotSgsRShveVFc4VuD80P48JDd8Tw8hMzTydYFXKPL1WhTTkNy2TyHu45wblvftCV2rKPGhJaAtyIyt@AUmBkyzsaTWwRyiKkVu84aJCJp8Y3BYoXjPrE3zqSl4hiYu8LIsWt84c2zgfp@cAD@B480iJZr88B2GrgwQHYGvdAVfQQ94KwjIAYeMcDFM9snXu86fYOaP2XbQQeuwaNYrMiT7zeqEoNNr4LFi@4J2vsfJaHLlkx3LplURSX4NGaeafj33RWM4HlQSaKe2lwrxpAyiBsmrjUILax2QNq2BA6wHvP3bbR9FymFGIaO8fNPqZtcTP3rY5h8y1N4604xHssi2YMCmK3tRXYj2/wi5iJAfFOh8l8BPH2hVZoPjQexNy9k6Ih9jzSHST@lrL7MrB7JwO/ChpApE6MdOrUU9FRRUTjNAUrK64DHInzth/C8MDOjUHdnIjg30P3xnr3LiaInJgYJ/n7Dil3UEV4ZV@Cr1k2nT60cRKrXTzbgVKw3nZ6nsXrUJkswfgWIYDGjg1Se10oTqRGNwdOpWg7dijRGnDxnFRrwJQPSZU4ni@SB@LLb@vBNUa0jw6zY9ScKzO0dpbARaRrE6dfQBHmV7Bhb0NXagr9UxrLjg90LV62UNzfvVA/vE6gEXYuFvjFQ/4mQn6NXhfTguZB63y0AbGPepdoab4lf3dQw9hiT52QltjKfWQwDmxbMK57Us0HYXz78F1/PFsy7U@e798XeCwVJROXyAO3rYylW4KV/SQTFKfCxF6PkOyEzIKsV3yfBOEM5PUTPCiCtZAHitgoR@gCzEkL@kKE@KWrDZogWcQdOaK6A/wxVqStE74iSR8lXB/JV8puIV6MJcc7R1iInIovohM@ZrxCZ7z/hPqrO@j2F6MD@f1wdNmFuePdwydh21@I7ZPypsbn4@LdUgjXw9F@WICWd26/Elooe2I@Yt5J3sUWcHrAnInlSLA7dnGKr@/UHbU9QIN9L86gBEhDqQ1sWqL2rSYqPEIsjGasEJ2d75dOT5nMxycQF@QeDhkaQgwi7iV@wQDfPWvZJOy0QGkKBsuB8uT7TGxdC458LGjMM4k3R1QIHSQh6BEIi8nr/EjqiZ6FVAjaTU8C0afcZO5ufBnklgXiWzSTCcIrMlbDggJKM4sZ4Z2P5YY3dQu6JbhuHN6TTzumed@NF/P0R2FE4c0/RgtPisyuv5dcP8756XAFy3w7oAI3QJPGuyk1dgYJ9wBQ0yZrcEG1@FWKm@a5gh3xaYc7vFKTGvbfnaGIkbgSznXhkFgXyrHIGtePl301h3YeYjdg4JZOEch3KEOAL@LJZytcobFxp6dMdkGgZOKVMU/CXAHRK7f54JZJZdxPFgKFPNzWlik3ZT@XFZydFbjz84E@w73N69PiYTopkLYLk1L/fpLivcRESj7NZxbGDwTM65nM6n24p0vhR1f/rrh5HzItP71uD8b3Y5TuyKXpfeDcw@cJP3zMAAtIx7fK@w1mKiKoOjP6lImyU2cUzh/khc8LQWbQEGm9jRfkTKYaY8OpvM3GznukMHYCuVOGUBMOCspbzR3q3y5ODgXyvektfXp6vLEhEO4RvP1lcLguZDMk5IXHRCf9zH7fJjB@LKnr4PExOo208MwcHZrjG1p5YTCQltnCBWiKQ0Z8W23Cn2KgRGhWUcMLtXBSLz89q6fq@XAJDw6PSmyF7GM1J6Yg5b4cC4mcJctelAESvTQdgb0GHcX7zM3BF/KQ8FECmehQnkK0id2bN6IIKMtlsvAutn0KkapPV3rTrRs2GrBIyHQX7WOISJOvpeOD2KwJ9VR@Ij5kzu3ZCsRKyKomU1Tww3lcxDSJgtcm@of6KQktnIsNkguu3zSSeja1vilR6eyEl@iWNyuJlXpBZtDnGnbXHfSvG5ctp33VZB3We1Mb1kfv3jKWWWN4xDf9mFsC1NcLeLpVYXhjUJZtpohhRQa3yarhhcwYWfLAs9pRNh5@55fQSB18aKycwxMQU1zKVro@F@JJOa/QLa9XCnYhle@W7Uoez@p58YIX1@MKejyGzhNEC1@QL3sV7Ep/GZ5tNe0r1h/URjBKCs5@MDr7gf07znCJPds0X07bjKVHuFkNz5BotnmtBFcLI2dKqP9Ij@gQj46nvWm6GGdbGhbkAKifAGXVHdLvKCY9SmmDnudQiEhIRRZi76330iP/1FGKJgwApGxV/OxsEZ4xjILrPtx3xHdDqzrXxnQ86hgLoShjTJJ28oUs4xFAzKg4elWuSK5mGvU2ZgIvkXtP0djWFr9d@haCaZIOd2oYfTr4kKqgE9c34NGjxQRMghRzl45vSFB8fNfRwX1oCsqj8y600V0iRRBDcBs3u6HjSBR/CwjACf@Iq1SamMEUihXoifyoH80doJG0yXE9riLgKUheKY@wsIibp1cYI6cd30QjTFaQCfwfXSM5Oa3gI0qg6vR2pxgBfIyDE0loGVq8uUhLqlIKKuKjM46mhKKpfjQfOESKR/dSAyeyYPTzzITmM2J7ZqcDmea0eDQmBzrpOK5IPx6k75YxzUqQeR6u3glXJ8I1Hs4zNYbSoP8eA@XCQHLkZgx3y@QxWOJOWgVGuokGNV3XQOMYw@YXwbqa51StMXAxqErOlUHA1kSAGgp5NaP2ecjSRJyAwYPwMg8X/J0WNR/kcgL2yWT6@JREBZm0N1ZsJZniUs22Otu8cwpCkM1khteV8@hY38R2vFGKI5NCnICChtP41GyLhTGWuO5LHGozcnHriawJZWJbmc4GP3R4p2HNaCMhKlGacSLckM4XQjoUvBRCQTiR0Zjfcot@5JGIPAqhRaglP1l@aPFOA4eiTTfxAh5jfI8/fmOfzJwPF5kd@IjnfMgLzw8jTxKIhO6SPJtMk9IEj31wT1GoBb3IOO3RNMbZQuJ5aJI3SNPkR6abOMu9FMiJsKDwJcUdugchgtJjAN1n33lViIG30i@TK9LnBqjQvY45ZDs4ijDoNJU0cR7dM13PRftFaKcRhue9XgcXFUmxu6YTz8I2RzqDqyljjKFlNE06xI07HD6BLnF@HCJp7BgxX@P@j3GAO2i1@N3kDC0XgWjFCRXL06Qde8TnK6DNrKb5qXCTDVy@KAqD@VY4E7zmeOuh@9Txxm5NAl3MBS1H4kVt8vYtpsvxWAhapIIuLSdJ3xlY9cu9z3G5dkNPreohkl2J1d6Utro2PigFRPID0ilQVzP6miSFln7rfOlXRYQJdoQd/VfAm@YVXqAq7UCPQYAuKKeu2b8yG5oknZrBGi/iRVbGhUc8Nu0M@nU@dwO6FV68iqd93QRf7QIOwyf2z3w1uE5LYQkJ16TGi8l02XwDCegfKGk6uPhL6xF4qp/TAyN1TQ@IshJjk1mipWWRF9JdujjPBNQwxB3qYukhIIPteFYdaoYmqqQOoOKrHOPE@DXRoZxAevWOgYd8tVkZwNMvYwr4GfBXihblQRJr4p@UB/9yeH8J3fBrJgnSz6G2As3d7FsgfccEplqhaKG8QwWfPz08Y2fHB@cvd05LDNwnp8dfHe6X9tnuN7SEjevgZMiUPT0@AukSLJbzRfFj8JB3ziCmTAHSzvNvWOnrk9PS2Rk7PmWHz06ODgEboD/deX5@WDpLsMPne0cv9mlxHTCw58fn7Ojw2eE5gJ0fJyhVP5o0jseOD9iz0uneU3jd2T08Ojz/hlI8ODx/jonhov0OO9k5PT/ce3G0c8pOXpyeHJ@VGBZM2j882zvaOXxW2tcgfUiTlb4qPT9nZ093jo6mCnr88nnplNEegFApd0uQy51dGKpiSlTO/cPT0t45Fmjs2gPiQQaPEuzspLR3iI7S1yUozs7pNwmB9Kz0nRcABIFsf@fZzudQOEm5hypQL3svTkvPMNNAibMXu2fnh@cvzkvs8@PjfaL1Wen0q8O90lmeSUfHZ0SwF2elBMO7bChpwAHUgnBw7744OyS6HT4/hz7jxQluZ4hBJb8EwkAudyDqPhEYdzlgaYFIx6ffIFakA1VAgr18WgL/U6QpUWsHqYAbJvbOw2CQIBDxPFxM9rz0@dHh56XneyUMPkY0Lw/PSjGosMMzBDjE/RbfAOtAoi@o1FhPkC/uBGaVfM5NUHWywwO2s//VIeZcQAMHnB0KbiGy7T0VNIe2nJRCkyWWg3MDRjc8gdK863VlomnCuzMvs@diAgNHe8f7JdD4uP0seez/Ajqd7JTho3AYdDRBILxOGJhpmLVBq2rZTQePigbR@PxG120l0Lp/DEbn7EJacMGDmEahCJFItfrVThXGuWfVaizxkJgT2bgvhpjkXgQVE2XsONx4A87v5HKc7FsThCo@FsuYtA0PlxcQkhP/Md/YZnTNGEsmG6aIhmfwEbE/Q@TyRZE2LpSAZKSjjGjvfpwkTUDQuyW4gSIqPnqtXsVZUNz3SECOCz/2@/EL7xtCHiCc@axWMoljWMqG9c70k@GJkGUD@hGGBawmJam5pnnZUlLh5HDIr7Ucp6HEYn4cgvVgGNhSYvdEr5mtqejqdHzKLC0qCyPorj/sJg0mWF0WJGOiXrQ@lUzBn6pHj5ifG266AedEKSmaihZzk8pjHh33GyWYsFCBhyeoklHle7bz9eFLHMyl0mv5Kf@ngT9vW7gbEK2qQn9XpngVejytcABoYGRSA0hiCUMXyWQojr@bJAC@BsA2Al1bDdzXA11126RuHUgCeuzA6ITTxM64bw3DuQcx/PnpzrPdFwcHIDkxt/9fe0@23bax5LP5FTBoiwDFXbspKJa8TJzJcif2zY1HUiiQBCkmFIkQoEVa0Zwz8zA/MB8wnzIP8yn3Q2Zq60YDBC1luUnuPck5sUCgl@rq6uqq7lq293f2dtsFHSTr6wr/fYv9UERRihEWwjYOYhp9MlbJM5B7aKUYAaIT8icCrtexIIbgVpNGLzFcg7bKSNspIR/D4UaY/GGCBnh2gHiwLYqj8bCg6DV3ZQoBOKmhujiaK39BEr4PohLRgJiqjJc0awv8B9vWy18tcT0gISAhMYrHCpQLygXxPfulMgQl3YbC7GCRmq3omIOuaRzQSRdZx6LvLP0S2jZmMWJDRVyvNO1UE4B4mIXCUlYTE17Zf6JwIXLOS7G@4M3XQm/w@FbC0VFwOj@Kj@PXgMaXuiYeRydnzjLoU2n5/MiDKdrY0D0dWniY7wpQtPbk1FjH9zBWA4FyjiaDnpVpuK3DgWS7JPvWpyXXumFKxRgc2E5bKFZ@A@XmDUdaaaswIPJbBZewuC0dq4Sxdq37KKgib3U4CoXOFJp@Fj6o/d8QJzntH4LCCa0n2DJC9t0Lk9Qq4wq0V0LK6FrdJxiXGAk2zVdvk2ZuzYm51AOTS5oFe88ACmR2lurFWwpSOHByEIBEjuca5vrVBmeXPmhOT21XquN1yKR3FTqW7BVqq1hp97xCMldFXaDgD9dy@aDJ6O5TqGg9ZRu5WBQu4GLdpfU4srmNzaarYnfUy3TooVc5keYlG6JmyakhS0stfgmTZOwyfR3tCETR27U3cmXLiGKZYvhyq@W2zeiW5oAFbdDnEQKaO260wGdT3HS0RI4H/oYi2GEkatSZcSuScHNdMrocB9jO4z6djGBeyvgat4sxt05h9pLWLOcxGYVgJ4mFYRIjEJmvWwOs0yZ7raGnY0qkVw39nyccaT3gIy5VosbBPARC0zW@Zn3mLxHm8f3GbSedbyJaj9L9v5pQ6MFezDtlOI1Ic4deUNN/HCUYUWY4sA8lWBL7S1vR6Oi6OlrAH@qrKiNXQRxBZ6AAk3lC/@1ahYDiS6ZvSC37bKIPkZ7wRuY9VuILPvHa1U9v8UnOmT0YFAAHb/A6VcQgBBnlJrzCW11tBB/GhvvLKJj1zWM52E37fognQCR@Tye07arTK4kg1/PjKFiCFNqrjxZ1aqPjfDK9nHSeTcf@cDQd@aArYAztBS9AfFzSI8b/HM6m1xFlIqEPfaNQf5k8cwQTjuiFv/XVWNuI8hTFQeiYN@LxbHl8yYEI6PAWzcwszTMpiGqYDbel62zvJJUKaQ9Hsvhquu21dbeaeZX58hgbkGV1lLmsZy/FmFxfDPfG9kqB7ocKGDB2rarlu2tswlIQHwCK6CYgBbECZuUG3BwEagdrIT7tLyp9Cmc3w1A@wfMAc3lEDr2u@JhMEDj9R3gp/cRq7jeMqnyQv8CQdviwXI/u1t5vDD0A8DPAb27lUUseIVBA34GK5xOxzCxxKQEWnTqrgpoAKMnT2WgIiu041WhnkW01/Xm5DhtkZAJbs0RsW6FKXJEOCN@YrcrpAMvpLF3rhx@sklVyKTIE7ojHsdNYT7DBXRaatPjxHpEPb5AxPZOWHQPodajqAZYwk1zGgNMEmaPw3r1iWq37zloGgV6eUZORIcCx1X5JPg4i8@DNynQGzNjOYE@sDUpRPA1L98TeWt6RG@QrD9c9173T1JSJzVtstsp9Qq23xMdlu5CFJ0M0aYyRURPQEKpQ9KzJPIvEhdfB9eZ1lnfgYR3OEhMdvano@e7z2sdN8R3ajKqNRi8pgh3jXbb1@9MODLyznoNImyzid4hjdJBldJb8aDSVQZPG0v0xRNQnsGfw0QfMYb99wJ05P2uRmrXHUtEz1adUvETEJ4b6RrdA4EvhAO//MRAZX5FoJsVRzYMnGNiVbpOa1S7Gq8UP3CA6qwTV5CyETxGTycrQEcWTHzgdNFhpIieCpyPzkl2HidcIozjucsAgl@6dZbV53uaWFrolkGWp1IdaUh7N8PO0s6BWVlABSzwHFXpEK7zp8v6j@rljgXLQAtemz2JL2qjgYFxrE6CBf8xPnQXKwElXUjO1otILoUOsAdYCqCHDccDaE0p/oxlTPF6wyzIC0Z5fO/hnU2pgAOjdhsY2Vln0l1jEFXTzanOt6hFXSQiKfyP6ZSmyqEvqEjQQMMRQ32tCCxghk6DHg2kK7mJSXgpQmSOo6DVxWcJLCrCZmBTmfEekSoHtHaNEI6/EgdlGNbcRECzyyySAgMySXyRpBTa6XFiMEnv540lKgECsaJ8xDlMhs5LGoZ45RiA8ErSao5w2rUpDKJg@bu@4qY@avunrQcP42sh@BfxoCE@rzezX/Ubqa6rbVitdNVUT8OGavaY@AipcE2DNFX7ef@T8YEbP1maJhpKRkjLEFHiCqtQ16m21byPrkNx@lYyh2jN9j5X61eGkHKn43h@O5W1JpPj2zx@sso1UgEhweQp8prwpHNYHSWC1cafHUaGiq0K5aQ94pdJOB9ZXb16@TMUV7S6VqctVMNtpNBpIw10zjLqy4sXzi9G0ni5dH8zH43p4/cnsq26dWD8maR5H0ydKgQ5gRmBNRLXpbMipBBAGKIqlq@Ipiar@fDAwY/bjJRnOHcwalxR3e4v2n5E2u/jqDR3wUJOyv17gAHF8F5ZefNc@y5nSiroJgdpolPrOVhc4gB58MUBLYH1ZQo0hX1b2NLBtud7RDW4gmAqDJosC4bo3iYGs/XEwHk8r1l@ms3EfXdEf3GYrvHxpVmhwEbzkIvfReUQBTytW8G40NhxXsYhJ6tic2pdUYgIVYRyjrH8ZDF8sQsc@/caGXQWGvInD3MRIxxXLHtquhB2/R7NMhwD2vUpf@aHTIzxlC8NOLws4eQKItpqVXNUnVcSlFCOCs7tLI1Lzwa1RNAAYukuigIqKTtNLI1lTXCPXPls0B4jDBrchMGFQj/vVQF@m344rvosHg/sxRQoozxP7qzNEOpGmFSjLD/CJ8Zj/uQrL@mUmYgXLN5j2YZXvYIUOVigUHve876@d4@Nj61G4uWkdH5/AQ7VqHZ8cW8/xxcmJ9Rx@n@DvDa@1s9NmnvvcvYGXJ@rlrXUCbdAB52bvcvYcfsI3Dx2T0F4Yp/hR3XtUaT/qeIdH7ah@enyCfuPw9Nd//8@//sd/1Y/lx3/jjxP6cfqNLlSr1eqPejePNm7b@Pv0@XnpUff0UXheGraRypDd/3kW@WPfMGCs9Qp3OOn0x6PuOscdbcExishaEC32HPjH80AD@@EHfjqLk8dZ8ohhOZPq/ji89Km6RS0ceaXj0sYGPB16pX8t0dmJvPf1@/fw3nKRl5PfPqEWU89Yx6@fvXplRr5Grk/S@yDAMC2YOlGuTUaTaASDuiiqnHPVU6tWs86r1oUGD00NOlwwDSKrmQzMvwmQanRkF0L3p6I24MUoHX3ziTzfk1xFQ5Lv1NE559/yRVN53H/ClzrUxiYwPCzfZnNpcb3E4QO4eAvjVU@buzvn1WKxWNA5uTo9YnPUW0h96RxN6hqX7mDYEyiEJQNj54TviAtoEJFRLFLGpo0eZxZzJqhak8bECnexZMjzeN5EAyloNscn3OzPjzIWKnyUBcuK5uQIgLLB8r5XSgAAeXgdEuOyONlsFAa90WCpr90xKULSO@yV6LVVtgYrTluWPevaMq6Hg6RBQAhKARQuBhvNNsjIm0LZEXE7HqP6DeLGKlFdSPxpa5smWBulhNPxcjiGzhwy54mugTsB5l2ZrPFEeXNhD1yzGwww1zmvaJ6wxJwU4e4GeBQx6YGC2ccURWMMC8UCH19BUkBEWA8o4UiKsgF6IzjjCRuxTAfwCBs@OnJxOjYiw03cUoWgUKlF5VilOBM@UA5d1wq5JGIVficXwEQedARJ@rDkWktdBYau1MS3h0JpIWaXQ0VawlO6spJsWiv6Ahakyiu8IMPLMUAKlqxROitgDUvrYjy50OPnK7UIM@LR/RknnKNuWnxHDhxLd6M8tqk7Nke3@XCVkl9N/FjQG06jaNQFZMVLNU0UhY/t12fQ6lmpwJ0JteBFHSIYX5VDvaLM8SlSChYhuYgzvA/waHeiqCBVEK8V8U6M74aLqZviyXRSJZbbDeJRj434uPeHiheHeE1L1vsE2PqOQHngi0o1wdTDmQpwI3eUNNVJO4QntJfH9X@pRW@fcCbHvMKixXcBANLEoWfnLEFS0qKmBGogjRSBkUyQBYMPUoQ5DoajOFWnIkEA2PKZR3GrUI@L/AIBNrGbwSza6tOq7Br7zIXgW5kHIONV34DR7rvif5tHe2owuKtx7kNdk4dELl37q/Sh@ZECx4QaVjCgD5dvJT1DtLniXkdxzDCaZD9NqlYyCx/sgRoXEJlflMnHhBoQbpHFSfUUsNHKYAPYaWYZJFy4kWreIGAkbnMnJx6VQS9PF4sEK8xb0YuCFIngtqC9Sm7@1v2mprI7QxdZWHxQCukA9ujEzEGHcsg2mbsCrwMlqEt8NmCNszkGRWPzCdlRMIrKiBep0amGI9OVGrrMcJUkpZBCdMDP05I5l5mqarxJ7fN07WqJvYpulG@RY0g6oSsuR/L1gaSi391R7bLTEF290a9b5d0kzkHaZkLNjqCctld/gOhBKwxK86Mn5zaPNJQOr7i8GrNIFiBcphqntuiKRsqZlig5SGJbheN5PH0V//IyPYU3lrs@/ZIyfoJc4IMYLCKC79blCR7RAtb9pdQC5AMjYARsQ@VHATwXCix5iIZpfxYNT6YLp1E5s8/sSnP3wLVJT9ZyWLEXgWZU7AUcsAuzBoruSYEB6Vz7XcAsfNYd9fvBRIUDharSm/7UkWZP8Tj/RrO7iJOs2sTEA9vg5VEVJpFeCK7pOZz5wyufHj@fvpn5y1ewCdHPLyY8n6@xvS9hM8K0QPTlS16jx30QNexb1JMTmrjXEMllyQfJpxeTaMDB4AxxIQcBwQoCuE89/ig9WAMN5vj57EJLz7RvwqResIQSsSHvBV@cXBQ45@wVJkXt8DugTcdISiuP9CmTKVlkBPygbMyMt1yDRf0x3vQEk9Q9hIpeK4THmYu5VsUaA4E2lMr14aFM2Sb3QkMfXYhiE/cuO1fzcTySka0MS40LK2XT75I6qTImr0nBS0eGWdwZ48B2T0ewShNdhhhVggVRwlQrhv6o0E3jp2PHRGgQVYUjT7S2iT4at@0PzA1L90dK1cDAEMaFjVJOcZwFQ92A2u1Css9aetQPU8oHwgFIQTDKIeU@JtZ8a84xzjCGriBmoif319DZ/56VXH5Dtw0JlpReit6vIDIwD0t0fbJsr1gNucQ2tFqgFE5@Pb0KRLMVdcJQXo3EZRzP8TdXWO/Q3FLSn4EqZTlsyi4PUwstJRwqk00DnVqIoZ3ZnAUaqymMmJIEsZxQfPMZz9LSLTtG57INVkqgJMOcFbKVxKRHmsPeoImVzbOixYiVT66S3rQEREWBpvqKqcrulmxskvQaT/WSHUzBmpYpTZHdSjbQRGbNUcI1GdyJqGAVUc2fhiiGKw9P/OUXQ1MaAWks3RYKeeSrWYeYZplrXXuxrPAlQtxDLQhn2sgRdLtjjFuXAJZtDpPGi2R/oIThsnU8BLaYloXZwtpP3rHWwwpklPFa1gdxbBU/n2Fc1yJIVwX4H2PsApe6wgOd1AkIiKz1gi5EPkqIDcK3Po0Qr3mrXnQLYjNUL3KmmuZe06VO7tETOoH@DPGe2SBexQxWHLBwQyGRo2x1xInt7t2P9ro1x9Kp8eUeSQNHTg6lmT2XwxCNye86pa4XJZqCY0Hzlmv9xANqOitp8R6E5zz1YuEBgMCSBoZ1g86o9qYc8EYBDEMHheTj3MQMi/VDddD9ezr/VjhWtgpCAVpAaCjpAOUzykLMEywSAjlT0gItPY5KgGrtypHbSyKqkbhIqE1RstrBm7JV5x4I6VmhXTqykiSes9g4Vcw9NVUnRFYxt5rlYJRLPM2gq6Oghwfh@pQqco3zYDl2qEPbkhQawGJnPd1kil2Zw9nYsAQ2OrLOyBi5in4KUQxHChlnE2bOWdIFJoQvCfGypcAy0VJfmHv@wAWkRLI6N/IFEWSviRySnNDUE7zPJxrz@dihqh/CDzlDTDNOLoQT4qg6/EgCTeHHIjSLzzuIlA70/n6o9EfNxH1JVVJHr6NF3ov3mrwXm3vPMqrjaQPuPvh31GNfU3JuTPYfq2w6AD/g/ZeOKeAfJlDyV4i1Iztw@yh2Jd31g0Svq0VxhzN3a/aLepyY3PX7sB0DsyXPpgroiTHZIFkGnpWBLTm5/6gNUynp3L2wQlAxEZSsZia1E73MIsXMUH@VZzxhaiCuxA@gOTIvIm9CvLqa9tg3HTYo/D4gz3TSa5usFqFCxBVP8ae4@D0YcKS8gaxkHoFV7ki3MgaBhwbBMtbJzI/vJWIlV3JssK@T12fpMKoVrFc/XiS7j1xWvrdcVizTmXY5Ec/KxRBki62f2MavK6clB7TQjq0ht3Gh0gE@qRyAYpigMVoYJ4f5wrXMK7efLvb9Ib78XjeG8u9efClr9PfSQkw5EWJ6uUJMUkBq9fDgjerp8sQeYNlOSEMui9jD/U3T/cG6Uf1Nc/vjZOBWUk4qT6lbfJ3TbXw9lRqaUKVDOn/M7Qh5La/pC1vW9oXlrC5onu9kG976Yxv@x96G6xoXGPDyjp3GmPo/5v4fYe4xhOJ4v7Hf6Pxi9776nW0Slp25b7Us@6HVPPpo72zxvHG2ONj@4vtiXDxq1f8yg79x8fvi7n6RH@EBfm2pX@@KR8VDLLZ7W1zWPc@DR2nl@CW0cvSJbhNLLQ/hn6Md1e7usnhU9aj6D8WjXXhotloAydnixcHZYr@B/9vt35P4Yd6uaOFjXashxVWRDYHvAsVEntTyaZQ0@czYHV4hCSh1PH1Aijs/NFolgNF4ZtHab4isAgTE8R/eBZIC6irA1F36eIpimMQUR4M9LlT8B7HV40qwAnQXLvyhLmi3F9EriTmhwk2glJAAbV08ru3i1fWFhKHQAOjAEyRmsik3qBcOdYwhtvDvUeMjWwemeGJL3ArbtPiXu03ZFfdlV/y/ohUu48vppJUTWL1oPYPpigPr24hhiSajMAxilviHwSSALRkP00dTFHQw01sP8@KNR9@x@d8T1bjVo4Y630Yd9s3hhmrh0rIfPYWVNboireg9rEr1jPdju9vqFzBuzBmGfjLKu2Y4ii/nXYqJ/2a2fBV/QZEo6hhXO@aoFHWQ5br1Kx8NByiSfAQkBiWAHczmkzrlFgOBDX1lMPz7lf8dgIb5TGFo/Q4Uw8P@7xxKHhoFIbm4LAYDmzL1BOP@6yD0Zz5HTUOr@bk/DF5hYBiYjOjSRuWpaH1OzjWxGR1XK0uEcZDDJSVTlSNYEe@PSsr9k1BrWehuTBljbPRTFyZEvNuukdcE1LLZtYCyVA@m0zgpz17jugL9TNegmGAwSewagpeDyYiAm@P4NxUQm5YlLwiO5Kd0mrygjgiamTXCTA44qmAyvyLa0ZlVT5tPziVumtc0MlyTxev@E8lqbtuIUJwmOWxu7uOXOdte0r1kQUIH6HGAYM2QQEGekDndFl6BphBF0@63FPcHuRIsSKS/mvomy57M6OERD7snwdAnXnHdHcVUoD@KqADWrA/fg@zOKKqkSLU7H0Y1XgvkWDGKonmws7e/TQDRjq@K9qe9VNFWHVqe@bNlnYC7jK/GehQH8aU1Dt4FY7FeIbApoiwvSqIzTKrlz8dk1rLrEukAKlMjBSw4BxV@9/zFy0@P37x4XgExZQeLR@SWpMs6BnL58yZ9H4wxUgOTEVbh5Vvr7m4zkTtRpfQUT@QY9Kcm2jdNgFUDUVTDPWAUOiWPqomdBTdshai2T4YVfR1@PZ19pwMX43JDUOaU7cBWyFUrv1hEl64I@yoiCaYCG0AdHJjy3J6NgfGsFFrLKwADwt06MVDkGPknUq59@LBa1WvqCT1VgbFWq0d8yGI/G49A8Sx9OZ@kuG2J1o5vlYDJ4fU/s7aHJeILNbttXXqox7d7XqOt/fbeOXP3RmdFHiAUDiPuzfRkqebPmYtnmg0IccnKWblM/u//lNz2bRJEZ@zELkb/t957KnhxjZn6C06X6pSiHkxWDNXe1@JgET/jaJNe3NYVutP@UtLePwOtuu@8N/sIHfcG9urNzZ7nbbk30OUsxCiUITDD4A206Lbx3SD1TruI1c/OJpgDuYyue19/9unHMOVoJxZE8ek35@VH9Uqp5LptHILvkX/f8y8@@xOe8s/cGp32v5xNrwQvM193UoPZvopOG@cEfcXGodVxFQLnHAaxjD46Wb7xh5@DtOSUfEABmiWRYxxMyujQF/@yNtomocyF@UFMHHl2enJt92boUanLWTBo81nFbeS9c4ZuO4Y/l2YXO9CF12pR6zFU8tCqKYP10QR264/ffPapVzr0LWzVy1kVpc2uJg4gFCIYB18dY0akFOkAVyGqitlbjwgG/tss2UfpsRzW/aNS@/Z2LTyfckxXEH5KCQH3nXlFKG7mrU5pe5ZQwTIMPHzBW9s/vXhjV6AuhmDBlxPc3pbEtNiJ1VN9MLkhp6AtcPkay3je9sYGvcMq88jzWo2GixFRbqG1CFOYQ7O8sGbt25nv9R2NSD8c5STsadVadXZkierN3VZjZ@@j6Qy2CA9zom9EwEI81FrejeLlBsiGgaeS/2yAnAy7qfdwu7z/xejkX74@eL373Ol1P2naFfvbiMz2Z6EJwMy/rrFYBDx2JvFeCQj0XOz59dD/blrf7jd6IHk29/rB3k6w39ja7@0EWwfdg4OD3mB7v9s/2PP3dnrdOsYbpyq1q9EEpCSbyR@7Hdyv23WC2X6rcTAYNJu7e/2dg8FBq7G1td3d3@k3trcH@01/a2u339rvHnQ/LLUl8BSAwSq@i3tHlgM/Xi/cFVZ4u9R2/x8)

I tested this answer in Mozilla Firefox 59.

I used Firefox detection code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eccentricpixel/5854631):

```html
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger=='undefined'?257:259</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## 260. HTML+CSS, no JS (IE11), 12100 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger=='undefined'?257:259</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ge[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dmint 22bont:2 3af  $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,0,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- (-q?6+50) );q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=  (^);instance Num(  );(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2qghUAQUS/AAIdPMDvM17u5sckn373gHR6AJQAKoJVKFRBRJoNjtmxhuzGkvhlcezjtForTuSLa@0doS1jvVKDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIgeyRFLEigsjJPnsw8efLkya@TNdNr//KXMfywY7czanVcn/mW57NG3760@jrbHbHHpu1lM6uShFA7/dagazm@l5NizGDMsa7YoVO3G@DHfPfCcux3Vh/CMoz1@m6rb3aZ3zZ9eLEhFtu3Ou@7731Wd7td02l4ALnK2LEJgc1B/YKZNc/vm3Xfdh0IWmPshdMxu7WGyQDC6vf6lk/oswxQ1C8ozmTIOmPP3L5nYfJ1y/Nc9NxgbNvq9vxREV42AcLs2@7TneefT0XeYuxzE3LW61jDqbwYafbStvqNqRiGwb46OziY9s2wLzXXYQe382esshd9z@yY0/jX2M7Adw/9af8s22lZjsky@paemQ5cZ7t981aUDda3zEbT7li67dSZxtpWp2f1GfqwptuHKvOtzmZ6M13dGcfU6xh3cxw4hbYQfJjZb3kQ6F5a4LSgJnq21WDNvttlpuNdQUrGVnoMj2i3JtmhDhkERmNvPIjdsJjn2L2e5fNAKK7Vp2BImXVs50Li3HfcdxuDuu20AM4CuvYGPpXJk@oQrch6god1dLAYUYGDQRZO3a4VrQsPmBdy7fWsut2065w41tC3HA/K6@nMhrq7sjsd1rA6EGGMvZ5knssGXsSr1jHbel2XkLiYCutedJjN6r0e40FQDMjSQXqTWV33jc3eQXin7bFhr8s8uwvBft1tNi2LvbN6bYjOug2p4UoMPvXeVMnCt2ULYBwLSrd3/A3QzUdyOk3IWoPVInCQD8ozldh0XCBfnzlml3NDvTei0gOaMEbTdXX0b7iW58R9duX2L1jNqptYbEzMs1pNc9CBFO0mVgfwge2xrgtPqESHQbYgso@0QNyYmDSzIJhMUL1WDxomVq@L7AJ1HdTyVd8E/uh7oh59uwvcYftxj1mmZ6PEgiie5TSIM3qhLHOhtNFKZ5c2NDwgxaBPuD2rT6xPeBmWAlCaIa8qV33bB47AUuywY8vss7O@ZamcTy2vbvaQS6NJQmIupuBjQXRizO3teOnoIA4MymPoZg8Ysr969p0vJJPpBbZczcO3IMt5qfR8n10vn6Oby0xg4l5fMVVW@MC81Pm5Bd@hUUu1@jcSYJWAKh2Wcnt@ytR6kEHNhwymTHSiS7vM6L1OJGG2PVUHkWbDoRpQGyAE2FdJKll90O@jdB8T1byAQndcpwX0hML2Bw6v8vU0VAHwX8NLMuvSQh7gdeReEYXP2sAh8A@gEcnCOxwiKHQ50BQFRYN0PbczIDiI6fnYHoEqEBUxHjbZV6xp2h2MAuGIiue6b3nAnBhn4DSw5ru2YzV0FmSDpE4f2uIlJGcCUvKA1tCNyBbKFABDRbhUVAz6@Ju/3Wi1AM9Ove72G4JdvwJmr1PXaFJmoXNjyLCuY3YoWwCXxNR5dEjg0uzYDZJypjMSSVAmKNUrd9BpMGqoVzY0ubYJwtYCAVH3Lc7k7sCHPCZZ17zgEtHmnAsF75o1qFhKgNKmYmvs8R7UUh2aOfGM1h34zU2m9Uos7qVeKY9yyqOlcwsyp@rqynIq1coDw@kr5AVv8UWc89XORFfh@abn2g2pN/LbrpNhWp3J9YLbsxwlPoEjnoz3a3FVR0mtqHm7UNebttNQ4tvAi0VIOK7m64V62c5V8lPRo0kCmitEg83VUuqqjKKGGsVlqgvKhQ6S7CtNuCJhrldFkmOwHvFGwkz7XXKPGKkuyJcuMgjIId3rWFZPSeuGimIC4WaWGwNmlXQKhyhwzq4k4rF4Ilp0wgAlnSgoNtYz20Wx1em1Ud8AojheD2RuH3m3bgL3eNip@aDSJVmN@Jp6QpAsJBOvrDhI7RoI0oCPqEnyJofxNRSUAsO4CU22ZKsRacggBKAt@94tadxxUTugPGHPA6LDwUTNFlQNROYF2eEF4SmRz2SRLhwQKIitZrFNrWZDI8DmBjJd8HykbAC@muEwgI03kojs6Zoj7NW4ajBuMNinmawL4qE/YnULZQ4IH4t3KJjIgNqfB3ovc5ssrWWy2ck2dquJ@f3UjvZdENLvUgtbEhY@2phQ0LAmqNkd02kNzBbIC9eBKGa9bvV8IaigJJ4Pomi6vyFPTXSeuteWlh9Pp02dSKAejdNAIc9rT3SFJkoXobZroJOh6sfHAqxh90EsQU8@lToAXE4lLr9GkIkMvJbnZCHQAIDJrKFVH/gg1YCBr9p2vQ08i7lzuFzkndB08uAVTR0ku9YMk8bMGMWHGUlPhV6YjbkoNKzR23igc0VUxQkPqvyox2LMptedgdgNswgdQcRXT5k68N4dOLuu485ACoQM0SLIZAivB9DETlEpho4rULuosYaaclhFUGcgNaDlA/@1fb/n5aCfsP32oKYDp6TO@qND/8hBZkn5/ZHtu9xd67g1EMsetM9UkEKqPqjZw6kCkV9Yh2886RIUsKbHCtBzvx0A1ynxpgcCk/z3EDgSJJPgJhT8VwZAAtKBUErTI1F8AELldOTUFXmCKeUkk7Htyio4MGJImi9QeZvM5hvwms4lgkUzo6cQKuX16@TQIjopokdwypb0YKJo98yj9ECW4adpdjwLns6g08HXgcOlnMJ1BZVdSw8egGhTKDm72@vYdduv8lD28KHQKdgSjPFQbWqizqRCnAdiMK2DQAEY0f1waN13T0nZVVQoyIObiYStft/t83T9dt@9YuSBYFKUqHtuF6U7e0kKF2rQMKy1HRzei76UulJzpgoR9qmkL8fj@hvXdpTr@NLSUjwXL0KPubT0CFzb6HqErgS4HpFLIxfC6eiiGElyYWiZYqBfJX5TDjAP1Qo2hyH29u/snmKWc7nVStIsG@KZwacKdIYeA6A1fACeuFoooFNV5eIVFFSvNSdLv4e93mm9b/cEEb4wL03@LqiwSmSAinP7ODDIo/KymCbdQh@0CxgM1NtKP35eTp9Xzq/PG4nzm3gSY6t5s1CDQkF6Sldv9d0BqCFqeS2nGRVVLa@C8lErxNPxFUXZ1GAYByMR9bNNNWFyaitxC3pD5fw8DkQV9CnX233CN0xmVDUkFeQDFR7QtZW4fr0J6dfUipqIQ1w1noShWyEeB8rUkQgeFRrb0gSBjk6@5ITZSyQkat4wKsXvre4U/HDQOxn9ePDuHcoujqMWclhnYHItrycAUodOAKtj4NSgNQiqNRnK0Yk0PnebfFS0hz@lpweSNaTa@vzooHRSoGTapncBOoXWQtgU6MpAlX5DB2nQGTQsaRYMiA1w1cc5wbkDTLxVrzPNZQSm1XkmIt1Fnc3BBrKGFE@XaZ3uZBG8NuR3b6IMhIT8KeYi/aUeZImDz8xTmOQBSOy906cTU2TdC9AnWN3roPKt9XkB4DW1wj0b9AjHGDl2SGM0BxRM4C3QLxvhXIDjOhrKwmA450YT4hMiAEF@qG2hJmFPwCDipj2EIXEM51OE6o8aK2r/e64Dg1NLf0nSUGYgyHG2ytJn6v/HXJHS6964dYKmD85ex6yDvJ9Edy6zc0AIEiiVmh2i5m8hnh4c0Dj@rjKCKlU3HaRfw6Zx6sD22kheGEtgL9BvAlVxkIqTO0S1Q1YHLbcFlLaGts9HrdDCTzHKE9NTVBwn7fBxBnIZ6siYqWDmjhRYtw4jfAt0ZQzl0yWs5FzafddBIuslQA2iKI91MIV8FnmBjXZ2DjP78@k7CzlQ7Ja3EaFtFOs0cesetC7H7bgtl60AALKmrnPGPnRwhhNGOb7ZgxZlvyMC7bRcGOpP8qBlhXOm66vheNNEyBTB62@gF2CzCz0GmFPm08PvlkANMbLpNOQ/eEvTJyxkBMt0GdGzzsYAYhWgg3yDNfldq9ce9SfYyXPFvIlPk4fUMPlMlgkqJORKtPB3FDXayLkPtPMgqBG4ZpW9RGMCnLyLjqsnSj@hrfBmAyWMTXmjb0CKCaS3Knxcvyi4zlMTciucKtCaXdc3U1/pIKLxR0INWbOZ7KXiS/GUpuGvTEEsU2SphnWZQik1xjwsWfWZuIeWVU9hKHZuLHDMJE8QOIc05/Bx6AeKyZ8BDcKY0@VvJRIo2Cl3Ydo809DJn7UHlmTV2y6Tz2GIES2ZDB1EG8bKGlAeFEAcl4TRxIqQ5LsDGNY1rI7dtf1DmrPvODh20Ul46yi1ROgeyJsxgmPbAoWcTziMOxmcVx/3UU6Lw5@AJCesMMTXOUn7ViO1Msb2zHX7MK70mEFzCpmQ9F0RkHK9XkP3h4CAxypR/@4F/fzzo/1S9Xjn7EkhNfD6qY5dAxnRsKpdGMx2oDnM@WDecIawBLxjO27XhhIFKN9ddE5c1@fKAy4c3O8Tw4gBjqf71aeHuyc7J9@IzFGPbncHHRPzmFueAghxnBLMQjR1t@aCbuEM5mIC5eJo9@hpgOWLF08Pd6r7peOjswiaN4OObRrDVO@iNa9AXyAIM/Q0J/1RpzG5okPD1IlZBCFscMyVZzA2ZZoGvxr68URxVKZjAKrI2D1qGs4CmzjP3WcZI7211aiZm5vWeqO@trbRNJuNxlrG2Mw2N7OZbBp@Nta3LPaewDXNGtLMDbj4rAhOIGEakHl6GPpaoOHAULQOGstoZr7C0AWZq2ez1sbalrlV39raMjMbjVUzs7lhWesbzbV02lo30s3aprG5ujBzkWygajV@69IMELQ6nCygQBB@CjwmmgPPPOh6V6yRyWTW69nm1mqmkU2vNWpb6exmo2ZsmLUtK91cWzUyRqOeMXJBXJxRBSnRhgpDrdIB1TQI0gwIVKWgM41WMa0yBsvQQuAsr6KI6QXLyDhwEAFrGDAQi8g4NSv8s@gfLCHjFI3wX0f/Li4gjzVZeg09BeAmAeI6st6vBZ5b6BmuIE@srYKoFPJzVvj8SALztZG@QeRXuAYdKd@1YZD/pd9sTnhnyPtCw66sM/ZeJW@@Aj259isKeytoJnCIb43w8ZXrmfhuBc0EDvFlOT5c8Z6NbipkFmiIbJ2Q4Qr5TFxTATMAQ0wbhCm6qj4O26SweUvqIq2ZwXMjhbi3CDdfLa@@4asVVbFYjtzMG8gZaGJPXdCfn9o4b9@caDFSOAI/l@RgGmFyImkckhkvkzDtcvb6jhxFxIWB7Vy4NHAOXdW0bmQRS4iie9G5HbMJQw36mQC9lanbIbz/6taa9DMDADvd6Zk5CqBpT9H1Q1drpk7ogROgs3IwOZU7kXzNag5gFJSq2Q667wDTtjYJslmr2fNAgRK4@SB4zgDLsZMBjEQz@ppuBMNeXDoBmc3nYc8OjwiwZtIgbnL@n00Q3x/0fYglnv/1ew2ohNtV1DZHNBYMHVXHuiL@aM6tMREVX@hndu2Oe30iDLnuQlk3ccnV7ISO2aip9jWtbfa7OOQS1Q0Mij/ACQt4jeecz8UEz9mJ5BgReXKdgTl2l9VnQBPs1JIIT4wG2R3XbBAZ@FDYtihSHyubV4M15IPCiMIDPc@8hGasXLDxVgG/PfAH/Bd3B9xVjXYPv4uaqIBMZ82aYYGKbNZsa0Gl982LQcPVQNOjImPG1mfAjktPk3Vas2NecGcVnbOLzwvYt1st0CfEcx7YVRvGNjQoTV3R4y6@8JyB19NqUFk@NBx6o6bQXZBCv8N/54HYYv9c6JhPNbtDP/eo9JC5iF1ApSNC45YmLUI0e4rMHbM2wqF6@9O5DBMkBQdkTqGeSKRXsdsL136jW5Hmx8e@kuJvbc2OzTdTcZLMGl6l@CYqjU8gU5nFtqo7KhY6LrtrdrRMI@KcK9GDqeOxawYozdto9Y7pAWv5ojqsS6g@@lnE7tgz1WHY1R@7FjD7ODvBFoB5q8lCbIlWXXc7todNuzNPgk4vwI3TxO1s9BOZkrZnEbZBOpPX1kLXbLng1n1cyp3DaPeQcnwVFdepI5yju/OIVnev8DtXtWi7lxb/nd3RvZuZq3tILK1DLGHXZ/YojfpdnIrbgehnNh0vZubLr3dm@k@2gWCKIzpAuydfe3bH9dgp/S4iS6sP0fjvbI6OUtA2HY3Wg6Lu2dFEpnpMF7Osc@rV7LTczvpmK2XCz9zKH/Sb2CeI532lXyi9DONu6RXoR65jiOdcsX@R6l/cVXe0NNHHRfuIc0EPPEuEiUXJ@QWEkQTuxJlduIP0JsXUU3y8PK8C@vX2lTkKnr9CzzKPukHP0huRvg3qH0bY2gSH3@c6@K@S2tri1Br3E0@30G7cVYhI5V50LOjI6PdWlbJM2vjEGEY6fX9h1ewMrIE1U1Yd1d5YuL99wSjk/plKi2Isi9lOnBHCuc4Q6p0YP94r19iH49tCAWN2bGjkd2o6M@VdD3T0Hg65j8FxjI7bEVvOoDdRuROjOOdkMeXavaBlu42JTGLIp0qkzbv1qQlF3rPou3BwxQeDuLZVWEun00K/icxfT7wsGnSthnHf2Px3ImHyGac8hsXZkH7EOTuN8VQqVL194Wk4qXk/6ZSZNyNAwFtbKcd2LH@Ev/OqZJa0rblu51OqEIRuw0b9DbRSXPi5qypv6UZiNxgbz314OHNSa86b9eAdkhidAvVw4L2IG6JTr/eqZg2XrKGVtqZeF88DRSZy70oFunmaXOJbJzrzFU8xo2Lom/rGwhbJ1Vm3ZnVM/hiury3Ct6WvLsQXqixCT6a1LVwP4ytg4xXV2JTc6o2AWHYDBjltq2vR64LRgdl4M/CCx1ygoYvfGcE6rTfOi9ezQVA4@Dux2hZRpXzXgWGZb/ZbFo5rOrgqLnznCedgVn0mcQ@7Zsvi56oWSc/xVAduHeajwbFz9qRHju86q0M0vvVjMStAY7qwRl7wnInw2agO9Tno3j1VN9Xu67RR6a6GrqdmLibcoSs6bbfttK023wkUvs1rHsCRPj8Rt6gQkP9Wu85IPkV3KUUp23E7nftQFuUjl5au25yZpxKe02pA1E/COzJrECAed04BQl9PBKJOf167aVsD6LI813d7lkZv80A7OFnEf@dJ0WBx51edhVo4QwAUCZ6/Kv47x6Yt0/V7PXpUe52BRz8UVaPjdbOq8oCSuQ9X2D7fdsT51mq5tXrbvitLNcv0HfsiFcwI8deFI9tehAo20/bRW@/YQLz@SEduKETDT/FxOK9KxeQS77ZCx@w6zrG9Qb8/Qkr4rsu8jns1lg@T@yfCaVy@@oCOeTkQK4MzgkkbwJ11wQ6yBUsgYiFxLoOREo4Kt2alQWEx5s4oTWzvjLSO1VX@M08vmio/ZSqyfvspU6Ji2wNNDtqRmVvwn@CficXomZ2V0x60vNvijk/YN0DFwp@ZNb3TwjPNUxXNKxV6INMRj3n0znRSuH0bnlWouYG1cHUlu3B5heCMjma6Njyq8IA6HMydNuvYPY//Mq2Zmakw3F5Cvg01mj1sFvXTsJp8LQRdd2l6XbePh4hApdDqfcur41Q6SmSuP3Hp47gtkMxah42BA9iZRbi9aj2z@sMeT/v6udUycXvlUxt3WnZmcAVgnV68vgvpdwamZ39n4PrWTHzTC9h3oXtmtuz6kwnKB8gCioo9ePwxwfbodZv4V23bo/MbgWPBnBMyGWdb5LMq6PuzRmtT0/XhwejF0yoRRUns/WbaIQv2iIcOXDDAcHNmWrNm4t0ejRtH5Fo0CW/7NDMrnjO5avYmgEXJXw26vYEnHrNTp3060Snq7gX5e1c2iEXtLUhj1jY7/uxp7MjMLOhcopMcO@dp4d@1O26LfXczzUBFg04blfIZDLcL3fWx6UOLcGYwMKV9z4VSnPTQ@rxgb4EnrFWm2Y7tL57g8X0TxkjBEwvDOxs8hZh6ir/640/FoJ3NpsjThRoM9O2jegcPxX/qSICLXeDCUzq0js7w3HyU70Uy1p5AGPQujnUVHa8tXPTJYZfqOgNfw13@i/qU9YV9So4NN9cjrMGU75SevVCjHELbX@/SQy0YCA68zmjsmrvxYIrxbAeUtfmyeBI6GE3sW2TS4IQ2at4RZ6eHp6dI5O@7s0Y8xyPofe49ZIIOZNDdt@q48nhn2s/dZ6C6QVfWA6HbPbFwy8CULJkdEaM9detmB@jTuDOZU0I7o68YD67NnlWD@u2MXbN1sVmI903fnKM70cQhjQBD1528YndqVv8NzQhG3PMGtZMZemINaRgyn2F4K9T8ep0r3DgtN9FGptd2vJ7rOvyXhHAaHsazxcIGugf6uf@Ku477lyd6v5mDtMnSHl3y7SZWgx/cm1fcvlVzO/wXizBHHDg231xg9m3LSz21ncGQ/JgGutvsYQ7fxpvWN3Caw2tDY7uyYYwd7u7FzWp8q7A3NZIClfjS9GjJf/aYZmIn8f13FbXNft3FtTPh@MSVs8iRsDvkeLhVmm9NqEGlDEGgmfVBYFfgjqx2urUu/cwdk0Rq@sSq4ZG7Gp0f9c3hLCVy8uiY8Jw6vBWINGz460w5hlGPendHNj1km6S43aMfEuhXM9kkSO65bdXfmeodsjRsRTSXnDJpRDuzIU1uggM1p2Npfhv3WKZ8f57AeG5fDBr3WOsKFlAGXQvXrCdXbuYyleu1iSPc2av0ocDtW2LrNu4ShKYfuFHqajtzWRbRw//R7hcp6Jir62t4gn8w1Fogzu7eFwCZH/Qd8bgP2x27nt@0h0c9NOPk9ufJFyxWFqLAgzcHdK3MKwTUpzPo8PmOVmRHV7dB4zvQBpsuuDokwn1Ls5xLjUwcDYPlyr4Z2JGZW4fTm0ONO3aHXnnheiAEaD2Pnqmed3z49OhM73nGgplD3PA3sDu4ukdZCfyggOSaP0V9SnvVFuub@0e7pac7TGmAkHEd9Q5osSDaa5s1yzdT5txxDoZa/myl78nZs6eJ8aFlpuy1@27XUqPBe6enScgI@@J0ZnA09gFwd9Mdzo1@WDIMChSHe8gOUWixwkuKY2fgZ/fF0XZPD4xqiTN6JHKD0yLgadbrA5wdArbVGQEqiplIqKokYj1xr1gXLfZgJI@Oml7YvTxLB06kcht6VYLHw/YKWzbZdgEgVDXPrVZAhQBXDaw8a9oB4h3Ps1sOZCBInwwOoTESbsvIY6C4@wHWcpktXw9z6ZxxwwpMzsmsUuH5xQ8lUhr2yFrQCY9eXjYrheW4psWX4@dOjqXjIbjVgQHrTHBzAhYyiw@R4ZC63JKYS2bAQlrmubEV6EjQkFHbdBodi71waKEWyt/nJkO4PZoz3ID8F3/QEPadyI5Z1/bMDhAETbQBk7Tdq0c83YBcvZ6J9qEQx1UbJ5cxdW1vh8HA16@3uVknqKwXB2ebwliMsAcHL8d8@jDMBecbXMPEg68@Zwuem/AQo0g4jBUUCkZUg64DKkzDb3s6O7XpTOugPz6lIqzkOX4fFyoaSXbIGhbu9aSjyrQu13HdCzq@hDn5iz/gJnLowLI4SBokT6axIiniuWSD7NLU6@4Ach0geWf1XQGiIJHNuj/AVXCyzEb@Kh7jJds9wOtaYLmGkuHma/Z2TplWYnG0@YaWJvJ2U1neOfn8q3K6UvjAuinrv34vpV4LwsmfaVvrnpxkAUj@BhkrGpyF4HFonMnLQ5knGJ7mtsWY6YrXB9qr40yGB7oDHnPdXtBsUAknY1shNwojFgq6qZ4DEzZdMlxGDGtdkQkbOjboYK9AhvM8aGDwqhJq3uoKy8qAL8xqpz7LQoJoBsgEFzd1Rueb0RwLRlkesveMJDdo4UY2DW@ckB20ANQt7AYnAVajJzRS@1ZtQLuULzN6Jlug4ixXC9tFckEv76IlrvKr82EmrZ0PN0oVGFcIop6fDz9LZ74Gqrt9iPUwhS2v9Hz/elkvpt@/98wRk@WbeJ6fKAExsXx9fHhcOj3bOXtxCrVwEwi2A36uLJA1yEV0VLTtdsjGGdAFFfxPkD/h21gIohVNVZWih/oIVNBa1uRl7oyIponYd0SfFd@zIuG3AYRMa9pMCvsF4AKTmA2phoUf9NBSGxNxhbUp4jIbew9sQCFh8NzODFlKpJJZAYilAbHuSSo2v7CPuN99KHYnlsVkezQTBCkWplcOw3kRZ5Lg5u@l3D3T8/7u5eZYFpebYBaUG0BD3yDOwc7h0xcnpcloQSdPUrewlRWnWblwxpbGBwmBeS0yIiEi4sJ2QWYyReCvojPjRj4t/8qCYgnhWO/yyMShlH9ZGjMmUKaAdmYrQgtRFMoBajeoiEwftgUNPpLFoI@OoLvmRQyFwIEcog4yrssCc4zsper4CYqBWAW5gqZ3TEJcyOu4F1V/kkGLw6JhHz3weJub01WFvY7H4D/SKwWuTIUNmejOjArTWAa@HctpQYEDWDXP@yi2zAkhL/O8y2F@0c4l5KnxxqS1JDpEIg6pQi/dMXteoArG2HPXt3Ls7cAlQxiBMAn1CzKxanKztFS13NgqGdiAwTso7kG/RfgOD04LqJ1x1Yzke5TnBg52VADELcSKo@p@Hy0p8zPE3FQjJ7krrAIGXSXNx3jCClioJXjs0vbsWofzVxN1nA5ISiyNKDhaGSYTKGyn44FO0oDuGzQUH7taUE50OtnIjzdqDpNjwJN6qDImmSwhrFe4bSUOutIrHF@@5pGXCY4wexGc8e0lTQPKtWwnMCmcQxvDNBWRY35/gBsXi/FbUYIs5Miltf1uJwI4w17muZX6@Ju/zW1knvvg/pFwD9O78Pbr4q0J7t8IQgwD3v5Z@JaBtx/zt1cprLLbhgHH@QxtPMw9CwrM@Vi@VTAUDIFxZSpQWOVY3V8dHjOvjjZ7sUK75jBSVyhmgnEKs7vAGZdU0QjOUxjX4xiPUv4K@ASYC5gEdRxUayg9q19R0EZcLpXCjOMSk047SK0h39VBJuPeDtBUKmhiqfXs@pqRgkxqlwFCsmLTwgNtHKGq5kAwSpd2r/C6Vmfb29tM9upmxyqs5zmDpJbNV6vy6zCjywAr8dFCmUEciDKOAWFFEU1ZNhOGilGxN4sbcRRsDZfzG6iECjkAREVvJ7B7ATqnK0gFzOxYQ5/UplEwCgKp7bgRG8kBIg0Qcdxo0HO6TY4PqeG8aKSV6tFqkF8iGE0M5ORZHFt@xc79c6ciDLsy4L6fz@BfB9z/ZIa1V85ZaNfntplRZdpIKJaGPT51XJxePoDcMiWTyqymjHU1wqGyQAX5xfb@HlBCCweJUbfsN27P29krHX5xdHx6y9wUQcanweIsXtxOnGt6slwJHfEw35NE3T1InT7bPQhIGc3VeIIXIcY7dqezOSu16ZzOSf0lPw94O20KuJWQkb4vYpod0g5o5/tt7OPQVARwjx9HupWqol7flCvbxXMndiv597NMCMf0FWQucJ17ZEA4Pp1NzGJ4XcAZXhfg6cFhdwNPuuMRSN@9GJ@bFx6RAA4eYAEJIOmpAGqe8IQMHPH5n7GBlwy/r8Aj0cfniMiwa5ijCORZcLMBNq2xPUJhiK9teu2OXZOgA2@gcUpuRiewExMa4NG9Xsf2FVWiKZACqkEgxBRxv8EwN9RpXVohM8KEK8kW2fYL8KkSNALAFz8eeG127PYiM1v7VuA6AW2E7Q/4oqXFvhh0Aa5JjxMLRawF@okGkYFQ8TCrfFQNLUuY9hsm0HwipFdGA3@i4Hq3kVWGqt62hg27BQJcUZPQ0j8zQK0KjQ9gocncnxMHGccp/DkeA4uS9JMsPA7HyM2yqdtOwxoqaLIoVwH9FP3jVy8v46p8iwfIzOReYJhuyt5k0BBNX7SIsa3Gqca2FV5qMGUQdGsLzT6hHQWoFkjx1O8/BSf0T0qza/aYMiBDqB7TGb0q54qT9Py@yrQit6XisESCRtXwoADQmhG0SS5iHKbgLKSSKkDtoK/nNPDxzu6xsqHrFXBTIipbxhm1PejKcS5KlWCUBFFyhLaAdctymCPOvTrnPIiD4RJZZmNoDXRGMNnvpGl/F2lBpWbFhxGLVuMWyKm6tZUTtTEparYYsMVtKa@nAO0MERJoqUBfcSweqIb27fEiBFwVAbHw@EvLcSwgEPBM14Q@2BwAk/XVZHChSXJsD51SiPEsPhHn7CGjk3bSS/HrDi6dL6fyNDmTv4E@9fU5dqpN0a2OUv9jSk/lr5XlTmGUAkVHLSrL7YKRWF1JJJadFWXZwa7@4UOc07lZBk2iqsMQaQhA2nJHzQM/g@ZRWHbyy@a2stwoZFYoBrzCIO0aInzwUvr1snmTWn4IPXUSfPq88SrLHpnaTOu6cQP5wxaynEoCz1yjZUK6zQSTX7YTCcyDvlzFDHxInZ8mSGafn6Zo@igvtNFUqyua25RUDWvi1l0unIDCW1Q0CPYMCnZxvKEaAI@tpK/OCpuje/CEv8QTZIw2rVpeVP2XJ0PuL1iEvIuTFTRu2JTbOgUCDhUgIr4mTVUFYfLLX8aMdSYry4/WVzuXiXg2nYcfI7/Bsuyz5fPMWozFHpumD0P21Mr1@f5m65JZzcz6W00r2039beX44vj46@FIPVfisb2jV7KxBqAbbIu@9/1ssMycD/u0Tyy2kpJiqRXj4UYq9fr1a1B58VMu6sUARK@oZS1eKSsbwqNb3NhYSa5vriRPHserkBcorqpkMuops@0UO7d7XqMBX7dNdwspMf5hjx5heuCAfyb8usMmOYc7Vqs1KJkj7m/HBvg48EXcZ999@fIlOl7Sh707EfFjHKNAF8tVzWyMMplJZ/7iT5ZuktfH1e2/@H43ZS3h4wgfP7p5hu5TI/vZ0tJnu7tra0kgHHcff/f4m52dnbX9ZPa4nH20pqWXtv/8z5aWMpntTGqp4nlGJV6@@FrOpNdk/S9@L149Pv6O52Hd4WeVGeDE3034GiybZRfsHXwumgz/yf2uEXGb6K4132EHCcpygYRNPJ5djZ@@imP9vIsZhhEb0V@VirbEjOKjjf/2k6O3MT9WzKRe9uHpx97G1jdj3AkOeFsN3i5jxdg2gq3fxEapQqEAzo3/9u8hfvELwIMho234KWYDXOujWFErUJT3seI6OIxMBtL9f773PSlWHEImisXDA5YpZlYEmxibD42H5HL8NigY5zFjc@3oMb3a1uOjTDazjW7HwjtZ2jAcRSFjGJlzJirPEFWIxTXwl3uwNrixTt0YC0DHdc4CjmKCE4BBiEe4W3gQ23APDJ6Ae3lumisbibXMYyf/MvKZePmH@Jzg5VfrS49f76dS20Xo6fGTyz0@r4pmlmIbm7LrPsbJvzx7Knzz@DN0Nc0FcPiek6eGH0HA2GYhWeVEClpZEMLGbyzqFRO0ZGGD@hXgSvj5y//rL3/6lz@hv5/S9z9LsWBri1a@rBSDD3CQXOzL1@fi1XnGnvGP48A/fINX9EEPcDlibjIWfopF/KF/8UYuek75iZBi@EIQ4yhz4VggsShdKfYhlWI5rKXLYjFaHvikwlcqBs85OZ5FSjcunygPiMZHj5bgj/7hE77i7xL5CG8Cuf1ZYsUFn8V9gBQrx8qVCm/W0yVa8DnRket08VaN9iqXUkwDQZVInACXMsHc8DlP3PF5AV9dr4q3lD7GGpNif@@fosRi1/CpJLSbm3J8zY2vu4/1V4l8XvyDnpcP3/DDXZDDyo2mbb8qJhJlymm5KLK8rbFKkReAfvXqq21An9gubxfcPfrqVaSXVnlVLG9PRqb4leLjxwkk7WNAUFyuMBhaQG3cbN8Ub8rbNzfb2/C/Tb834gm@N9u3/ukx/syBGYdXsP7Py6nieUq0ymIF3nVgavDRU@fI3fAEuHJZil0j57ByhSzGFbSysZ6taIxayApIr1TOWMmsprLDz9ZLGRACHoJnZDm1go732F2CwrMlxXDosMVHEFvk8frjt/8Hfs8/fvtv4RWyhlfzUWjtLf49fYd/b338O6vj38lb/Dt7h38nPv4de/j3rIZ/UqzAGGhsy4/SnfRl2rgwLsBhszQozO1022hAZ8PSFkuP0iOW7rpGA1wW/KXBZaebLN1iaSftGAYEgsNnaR9dTXi04K8JWPrwZ6fTiDx9ySCVDnZhZGmZnu@rTD2Xyiz@2gI1Szf0tL5uVyvZ9d7bcrySj6XOz1Nc92SZtTxZ1r65YaxaLT3fr1ZTyPznz9yj8f/RUTf6uvC/e@Q@O3K7LvwfHR09OwcBVkw8TmiP4VMoJrbF41GsmH90ntOQcQMWjqW2H50XVzV0ryeAKzPol/jEzxgjPItL5xKMzV@@vMpTP5u/usxf5ckRvnJHVQAIMO6AWHnRP4MPxDt/maIe9Qo@l4SX3tB5BYGBiztSL6/OUYOE8UL4D@SIvv49/Nv///p/9oIp5YoKjeD6Zluhj4p/qnp9c30jfouqoogXZRv@0APeMcr1TRGdBHQNrrKiVtSbG@4Hv4q6zREWMY3tIkUeA4KkiIVpUrr8R/n7fWLa/HMeBzUJRtKKWAY8Px@m02q@Bj7hWoD5nlaU1DzttVmu4SogjB4NlSCya/m8scLdmbVMPr8mXjY28/lN4V5WlK3bn2L6kbG@nsusralqPp8WsDBOzAdOQGF5Zj2PjTwfUzGzvOUraZyNpDs14nJOfvhQEbewPOr11IcPja30@/ehV7XasPvVKvqvvn8vV2XcllPYysJ7evP9exA6cdXtK89dviCsaAb7LFOkFLbcPpRqA4KZkcqM02ybnun7feWd3UvKuJPSk1Wyg51Ou/3z@C9@/P3vn8cLuFGDfNcMRICpsOz29vpasbi@Bu71TSi4vMx3/iitxJah3iynZF5cJi/HYyLI2NxQyfcmjuEsts0eFaGhevhh1zcxqj@2llWV2shSr8En8DO2trgnW1tXNhNb4q@wpLLiChN/5XJ5NbG2srHyuALqze0PCtX8tVmIp1Lxm8K1mcNZq5t8Xdy3gGeczIcPV7eAmJvp/LlUre7vnO1U8apGXJOH3o@hJ0loCddbe/14maYYs1uVMhasch6P5/KPqdqNzSyLxfMCTouDtGebW1T@mOdJdhMPOw4J69R3JdZjxsYqdKvQq0o92h61kWYNXGHuM7fZXAJPqDtWw80AntXpBHdUXLn9TuPKblhLUuz46c5e6SyZAQ0lljnY2UtmTl/sxgx8zY7fMZjFVtHjpLSzf/QCYhw/Le2clj4//Kr04hj8PenNO9OyTGtgWVfVweDqLd5jYFWtHviOP1Wrbnvmmzdmjz4wSuHC@erjz3/48ef/08ff/fHH3/3hx9/96S@@/ekP4fsH8P0xf/74321l8fcX3/6z3//4O78Lnv8Zvv8Jvn/yi29/63v8S@9/Ct//EvH7U/GNwPGvBLh@/Rff/uT3fvHtb/wMvv9SfH92@/ubfzL7@9MfzP9ivJ/8/mKYH/97@P4hxxXA/vh3uB8@b8H/Dof7jZ99/Bf/gf//ufhD5@9@/Bd/ij/i5Z/@7M//y8fv/8dMZvPP/83HH/744w9@8vEH3//4gx99/ME/znz8rX9jpKM/v//xp3/03//4D//7H/8v9P8H9PuH9/n/@LN/@lf/51/933/1x@L7J/D9D@D6k7/6j8Cqf/NHP8f/n/zR3/ynn@P///6v/uaP/te/@fV/TY7f5o7/91/@O/7719//4V//4J//9fe/nfP7w4W/397D/9t/AJ/75/M@eO5Trk/1@fZXys/fhRrjVIAH6MIIlgEldndk0XTFZ8Oc9BmLFVfwAzK5vJnZTKyA/rmytQWCuUL@2wjCJGinP/0nH3/r14D9/wUgg7f/Gd7gn79A0I/ohX399UQgS9AUiJb4@msMFGPGr6NQPwKP9ynQxtOP3wPE1xTMPywEg3T/NwIDOCbAArjJDBAM7vHk/r/49p//HgWEcdH71yZQpgPvKPQygr8PivojbPfj0kShf4Si4@PPv/fx9/7xx5//9sef/zr2DdraVnInCV374lleAMzeAw4B1@8DB4AGjhlhjL8kZcCxtI0zk5KReP0acr8ELhhyrUjZVXiTjCK5DXRDxAS8EZLhMIG/8C@tbTF8AZ8h@cKTJSBoN4EXiSekYQHCCBRvIGfoLG6C1xDnFgqAFyPxOMnqJgxm2HCXsEDMQuKEVVcKQx4xgR5FwoBsI6HXiWxk5MRmYR8SLAz3GeJC5AnpNTxfF4qbhWER0X2gLACOxC4kCVB4wXliWPwA7wXCCfDScP8DZGWzkEgUN8GngIVMUGrJKqVpZKlwVPYEo3KjP2O41/LRY2gysrEp87kPICUT0PibGEMjIIBD@HliRRSH/gMnfVcwPtTTkOjD/Xj4I/Sm@AIA8GoabtGDr6Zhbh5D8JCjSlCy8EhwDEC5BGlRAUrwIIUlISWofhP0AulDHj7ts42iAtFhcZaXl8G1XZRX5eoRjCFhsNa/yHm@2cclRFIkc0xe35LRG/c78Z2cy8c02FzZX4FfA/5LS7R7mcqSX5GW4zhtEedZg7S0xKq75sZ4MYIy0tsKFSFBgOwzCMHv48fgBhrRc@yHMw30n5BexSQWo7qHxpLkv/DQC@QfaUrk8aogJcbvNJ3NY@h6Uk8mxVOnJ3nowqFTqHjqy6QxMj7uoYVqZqyvMVVS6KouFWuobpE2Jj3zWrvuEMYcSVlOGuu4@KSKeZqzXAZbq1TKpeH3GzeXK3ww1jYkeNL7AK8ME5dXAd/gxen69jbWf/Fao8kkdILOui4Vi2LdnRlS8bR0BuBnR8zIpHUG45XrtY3MWnYtm1ldX89uZIy19a219ezmKkjW9XQ2kzG21ta2Nrc2bkJqPQbhlMyt1LLbxX906/M//KNZn9m@@JGKX7OhThPoN1KxU@D7P5dxDV4@T8t5mtkiWi6X00n8y6yuwi/kM2lkNypLS51rDYt9TpsOr3GXA2RVutaw43sAHyY9kNgD8IIPpIGrkEzsGzk8yos9AnjzJ98nIBtZYGSoh3PgZI4OavT6@jrylWJL3/2uz4pFGHdohwdSDNpgmwWr4prd0Ns6XdjZGPQtCm0xtn/41eHp4dFzff/wFAYC37DMalqXYjc3N81wLYdeLXZ0dCSh8IMB3qqB8W/qbDAYUGgN3m@GptSLfvL4I2UyWmZVWzU0YxX/73Bk8P/@8Bn4z@AvxFrNSPyUXweP7gRTZlvSNrdZUQxuYtdrbmOk23ixDJ4dK/ijnkWXY9AJuDNuGr5QiIdXncYfZbIbwPlb28JcVHHb80cdq4iIrhu21@uYo5wD4@kb3CGaM5uQi@s631mRkzPZTfnmcddq2CaD@DgUw1Gy0sU7GHD/cC59nlavZ0ZdT8s3N5AsJSdtC3sTRVrwLkMjqODVdOXKdmCJoih9@PBhSHtMcoeOLzabZNY20Z9J2PIfQpf60ODO7PrYmUbnGVoNeQ5cCE3XYU9xz7jvsjOX703etepzIPbaJt3Ut9d3Ycj6q8Psms4FD9q3ufmCMOiJifaLva7tt@dAvOh18Rij1f8Hw1Dq1iCDyEQcYBd@@h3XnQWwwV4czynls9DaEO5LIXNDAH5y@PmTs8jzrLSz90RaZ7tHz/enHlkBlGVPSwdn4esGDw2iZkMU35SePp1@FQ/oF/I0R7HEshuBw2Ax0zcLcrIql9laJe/fPDK2Hz40llPHT3EW5LgPdOy4KcbOP2jbX2nFzXzfGvrOgL3YAildLEFVA5K9fmF3uQk9Tcsqg9Q42NmrQKl1nAnpWHq12OhSG83UgN9zGbZqNhlblp7hRtgtg5/qsj2JjlbiLXB446MvoWWDBt70jvNXNbxyfdBjcz3hgV7ohIbdho7vyg0ApJppMvh@6gfiR@czgGQLPXyeBvndCunMAMedF3aTpSWdk2drM7u5tZrZTG5uba5ljfVsNmlkksbG5sYWdDlpY9NY38xuGcnNta3VNegXITS7tSHFoKuwm6kUKB@GLMMzB2idOl5cso03wLh6uyjFuIxj7xRThUoP3wdMtiCOjFfoeT7t9V@xC3JmDQ/irBoMMJqszmIHB3vpgwNZ3sUXXNTYS8tyA1@ym@n0xq4sWxSyB313RpZdHgeCAMznL@n07p4sDzgCNIMky218Ka3jyEiWbXzZ2zk4wHTe4EsG4wPYBQ/hL53gZQPAHHxZXaWhlSy/DdEB3A5PaI1yWsIXTBNDDnjIHoTJ8udBftJpwHDC4TiGJ0FZd3Zk@ZC/7OxgyBdU8CzP6pf4skMfWe7DCzChLLfA0cJOQJZr4ERWlOU6uOojE/zwkhg0jeP4piyPOIGQRLI8JGizfiHDAED4YzJPnjwx237DavHPqM@fdcgahNjDQemg9vnntVar1h/tlD4/wZAvvnhivhkN@rVWTUSrVeHjQhwIueiOpj@Qx8Nq1ezMDPkSQpypkOqoamHequZbyJP4tDCRbvULCPkCQmbMvA45Nvh0AbSGn90uPHfNGoUEHwqh57BWk/PIqNiN40wptpkLB2RBsmvW@24e34eFJRZX4slReT1dyZM/6ypMvU7nbzC8qdBFpKg8oy6pXo/Kw0K6AkPDjYw4MqTI58NM1paTS91HxlY2t2Q@MjJriWEOLV27zTiLa8YjxXi48k55rj7KrK7l5PNHjzS5bFQeZYzN3PrGq5WBLKs5/H20upF7Bxp2HNRo/FHLG5VHG9lIlI2NhJnK5DY21PwNEMSHfqg28K1qVVGuLPNCVTHD2Lsr6jWVlo2opHa@qQyTwwLPFRsxNT8sGHlupIGlp5AxRWmgmaABXvqnMkLaYoBy@CidQzGtyMbWpgx5SKUUVUXBhKIEnq9fButp4SPimHDyj85yGr8z1NhcV3U8gVJ1m1W6N429jkLiMEF6icfF6Kh4sKuTRnZeTjrDUQX2BaRN2TW8ppgMF8D4mhu3YnyqydjYkqSiUKqP@Y1NefH6@ZM9HfRs8YYmh/QDvJ3e7et4q7I/EcLN4QReZ9DR6U8s3KtZD/z2@CFuvTSEQRQeVMlfay@1m2iMUxg78DTwHEue7C3giXC0vWQ3mFkogstsKJQ8M9UrKma1WCxUC12r2/NHMKrkC/JQqCD280GX7TIOi6fLgrM11cIulD@dd9D8oIWvy8PYUCo20LjSbmH3epBD/fAmbxWsft/tyzE8kffIKQwcz2xax1YfD4MdHkHvbeGpq3r79XkJAfeA1tc3WrHPnHEZDj1OovBoD2XoGjMkAqqF9E0@mmvF1Io1Nd8qlBH0Pf5sa7Jc0bTy@wqMEfNSEVpgfhQzC96gxu@nTNdgeLieH4KfsbGWb7NaofZqmO8XejCgYfkOEDEyUGNmnuDfd6BLrerVwnBMjdVCOQNDtXQyGLxlcKdfMpPeSmYM6FOhr4WY8N2A9zX4GvCFcAOHdkpHgaGYnEwP07qRNCwjqaRf243XatJ3Sw5USDqXw3qBKqVXeJpqIrPSURouM7c1qmFo43nKtplss56dbCsQ68QyOxxc1ZiivX20nsimoVnm30Ke@8tKQ99VH63lG8ouq6rgAToCfDNsfS3fxJ0Mr9RJGoMkyytLasGz3hJFUV4QOXpLUCFiAOsNuuU0W1o3ktdaVbvpmJ6/bGxkcuXBclkzoLzp961t@btFuQKVc8Mk@IsuhIEakge/QC5wxWWseoz9eqhmdiyoR2MrkxcgUk9IKkVW8PZyvrVYicc3MvG4Gs/jvM0S@AtJRyIpDjIy/tB4JIPqI@fkrQyEj@XbrRzwgeA6jFhvJByrMRgSxq6lm@ub7ej@py/ZaGQmtOD1IWOtxLLEUrRDQa/G2BK5NL1Is2s7hZ3WyU5eQO/sSbEcbc0bb55i5@IoNtNSS5@6LyKxXXzFn@e4BwiSlcjgVplVxMA2swqFbkTeoYDetcSpyvfGpLYTRZY6l2SZmjdfW93Mqjyv7EOMLq9ge9dNIZZyz3C4yBQzx5ttuaJ@eG53rjdXNT7kVFjsA0ukdNreVU19iEHPcEO0Dvbyffk6kwXqO27gAYNLH@QfdCTZrIzzSNZr1jvderXxavPVsxdHL44O2ON0bjO3OTWRfP44mTTiRnybPQZ11j4pwUjlPXOzxgfnC77hMZaP5Xrx1bX46nTUQmxYWAsWzxWjWNSM7Qx7BLzKciCjmsa6ln5f5IxXpID1DIR8/LWfrQ23N@E9A2pjDmiaTWSKRWMlo8Z6H7/9t3hk77r01c5TFkcDCn/7Z7@X2fjbP/tXtFIbv8mjX2Z1IwaQ6DTWN2LX173r6xv48LBsrBLjeVrbUMHNdxEYsWJKeBsbhhrzNP4G2c3GvPfCooqSSW9C2N4Rf5PXgZqxrZgU23z2@j1j2zCMLDZaLTtDrlTq1sz8cg6GavDPPuBM3Adt6XWhuJwCBsBpxS2MEMwcrRSLxRWc8mfxYgKPn2aytPJQvslXGJ/awYHKikN/lreCf/j@inuseB68B8HwirO@2xbLFg0Gg5tU6uOv/VYms/63f/ab5@r76vvqd0D2bm1trRuZ2C8hHwvOhAWjE5rWwNNd6AhHNWzOxXl6XZZiNJvDOHwwxsFRDZ6I5vZk8E26xM6YSFwFOpqgUioEtoInW5KkXNIxWDUvSaEKRspjv1VPEg62glZKoe1I19IDDIJOiRVANkkPxqjAo4uGaOpVrzPo90gPUiieUUmyhxAFUniApguW6ESOEHCakWepldtReZa5FRPq0FnX8jy0XQTyV3oAUZ4Cl9J1J6xn4qkuhORXqCMI5ZMCGmVIuwJpd3iEKvkqVHoOkGQ8dzySA9ql9ACPqJD6CX02s7cBIM9U6QEQAMqgCMR2hW2zVZVd24lEfmzs6Ab3WeFJdzM4MyJhNMTWwINSQeQ8wtncoMGgj0Z@mKjhuhX1DJBwHHxBoACKMUanN1RI6FjYvVEBLjoerFDR2MOH41wVCnZDZVQixI@WntBA09gyza0EAFkwpPiskZOTzEkksLIfTLIdUDxB2QWu08gxBmri4R18vZEk@L830yJHTlUVBeSxAKK@eKuoA8kgMpKd12EdbVUZmQ2VhZmvQ97rlCkyehGOk86Hn@lke6bOs3gj/TIWmPmT8FriiFYv@Hb60BADuTTAi1/wRDQXBuI4EL8SAIXToR/EDmNBUewOQTftPqjRtLgRmM9QVg0VozVDH8oH7a/KrDHc@pRV8UGxEBqNLJhosECks0QTt2Tpyeu5Dlk4oNOiuEGM7E55ErfnwLM9cK5MslXEU6H9VJEccQNQyPlkn8jhRpg8HhcXUmp9GOoFtEkyq6WTKY/MFlO4STE8Su6E6FSKRBmGUZGJNK51rC5k6dSyGJ6y93KpVMv224MaHat/ZgNftQ9s6DYcLyWumEld2Rd26gytQ2puE7RVcYwrxr4yO3Zo4UacXScDVR0b74THalUmzuF5LLOeBHUvCZQdf4GwOZx2xLN2aQhOcij4bsBjgzs3k5G4S8pIvf1cNZaUqkpqARkf6eM1MpemE6Evfd5LYhzmjbzgkC2d@oJ3PRS50DL5SZs4HrUJj4BJ4jRwgU6q6jgf3FNAnQrOhqETVEzrEiA0Q8I@BoRmPTi0hq0YSvuAOgBqe9Cy0AqF38/hac4C2mdS6tD0hIB32GdsNUOXc/PzzeI4MuDAqi9MYocwiIrl8PwGVIzOR9ggV6B1dhsQFkOjLJz9MH7A3egmiyxj9mZLAh12OpRWgfFmEbxkIy/YOrh9LSj6EgSuQw5n5GRJkROANiGrMkcdxp@OzrldIlmSY7cxJRliEKQGLKgq7Joet1goTEhcXV3pZMVk0Ld1y0NTkh5ej5XqtWzQRt2UDyNpcQuAjVe4iOupxi6Nm5LF29QeDekSs62HI/6UpCaeq3w7sPuWEm96cewDL0FW9lpdOiKOh7c94psDm0yr1hVab/MEm2UqyeuAzXLIZtpm/AaRMIZohslRsp4EZMla/SLZvGrkRcAltTtADpVlBZ5oYKwfvHS9wGX3miGE69NWzeC91rmoux0XVQ@ZTySOk@YlDCBHwat479lDiORYV2yn3zdHCoWrCI18qoxIu2Ej6N0pBJzQm7BrbofHHpZHlYnowzA69F3B2IP18YC4dL0YKTd/hOFDHj6E8CEPH44TDZItDytc80KvGywOMjfaewkgEc0ogLnh1pvGIYQZ9GJmcBQIOZrwu4FvvUCxA3rzN6jHQsAYwBNkNE1Ba23l84rjWVcrlUSqBTwtEyGgxgF1uUI0vWqEbqR@57LTc70JLwfNoUDnI/KNXvW24AbOK1jGsIKIMTi9bLSa0erqfKKE9/uiwIAB1S0IRA1gx1dsNR9aq6RAYJyyPKYxz1hZZKZCSpYIEn6gFXHSc8JGEVUiiNA/LBJkE0JY0HKEoWAhBF728U7FAFYjS/ZkdjNeiQMlp5oKFyl5qqRIrjQtyCaQHbXSwnRRgnCoivJUUKSYN6L@o9lf@uTsN6FdzM49MSzvF/JStKlYQzQyaInmQlRlxUKkXiEHqRWzY/WhgypxNVR0ypDMSioYTfB0sAjcOKYSqfy6yuuHdsHLjpwLWWFUKEARRwXeLHm7CEjKCR5G80S0UcAIIj4XIIAjPTOaJaINo9GGhQIXHGw4J9pVJJNDyuSQR@HQwzmZrIhoMEgKzS9i9VTQ6hYoVDLgM3hviRYmZeaZl2hGlL1BKxkweArSHMsc4gLBQ6hJI5/VKzNTL0cyHRFaUwiQEW8haPB7CXLStMAztPAtlFGclIGM4m@CDbisAAYjEZznlpCUkMloqAt6vZygfgDarpwoS7KB@13oL82/cjLwDL7Gbc/0JKQx6ZlOTv39g3hWkLKRBhpRMoz0GgpkHLDskGEIUEuuXKbMUJ7BPxVcPJmqddxaqmvi1gG8oTa8jlINxgNk@u1xz/VN311by/FBkE389UKAs4hNcD4GsFuOC0ONqKU1m1uGc@JoAK/uthzbs5J4ASZXwS1a7eYmnKWo3iucridJYtaPD0sRNWcgVF2rVbw8pVpVPKvTVHOhGUN81ZEP43EJx7PgisQHOSSQHvUUF2//9dW7caIZQhHtzK5fKEc9ERiHRHYYCKs66PMQ2gZVhXnueCRI9sFQNa75ChmwbrtdtwXqHdr@w9hT6A/HuDFDZq9HeUkyE4eouYixRmoOSj1pqiLql58clX2ZUUw1jJ@ZRDBBjCTrT9MYKdufkVx1bnI8WpDe6afn9zSa39PF@aVR9XSe@VC7wAM/LelVZYwBAMfZWL07G0lhavdWdiayEnqjAsUj3DuLDdqa08Cc7gDojgDXm8AfyfDNIwMgIuNfzaP/4goMopfuW30m3iV1OgJ508UdYAqZcPeCxR8FwA9VlD23kwtZe/@eaQEs6BHsAHUF0FdJcDloXQYaZg@G0Z4cLnkIxHfwPG7DucX3tDenwANn5Kl/mWQXmflVtF9tWB1zZDUUAZmM4A1KfAIjM5JX9ys4CjoSei4f1CnQSalR07RIdA6Um8MyZvIyYpj4FgwHsUPuoZlvyuHhfPph@C3RjFN2BT77DAp/PB4jG9Zkcrw36o24Vb4Ov@hAyFHe//CaxLOAdxME6CBW8JPjZNVF4vNECYt0jx4hhNUni0z2d4Juy@32btfhp5Ho7pJC5UYiFYJanrAbPK/G7UU1HuGKgCf5es79WPIuprs3z0VYjSMbi7C9T@tCbmHGHQL1uhLFyH0W1pjr3JIJ6Efzbs6cXqU6Q6CGMUnS@TaNq0m/UCUcAh/CEyeQvoInImxZfpUzVFA2nKMSV2IwCumavYjWInxAGwcsESoG1uEpGxEoKXAD@PVNmGZ9bpr1W2nWJ9IMW8BkkhEgqT6RpKgFrJ5FVdCxmv4c6YxBOEiGxyKxDR/HNfs4LXEdt@M5O8nil/EcCOS4Fc@VFBDK8UY8t08OL547JcdFPPclOMZtK/4@nguaBQL04ZUcj9FfiHB8r8dze4p6I/lowD9IV4/nwjoFmEf8lSgCpMByg9aIS2aOK4rp9y3o2EipTDLkGC@J4ySacEnSNw3/3FI3v1ECAnHOcoWAWYIZE51GpMfg6UC3EdhwnNGSc6I3Lx0d0A6bsSl0CE/AYC4ah9CDGh6LTwojnjEMpRUKeEIGUW7mZueIGZP28u@RHZE6cChV8mT6RD2d9IGGQuFlAK6ok2bYRfygviZR8Aq8Xz4x8rx83spOkBzlCNdY1RnZQqK@ji8oFNb11B0DvPajNURz15NAePdaAMJridBGZDrocLTYhon13N4kk1Ao7mqzo3Fo9o03SuTeqWgkFUTLnBNM3qJkKBiijV9dVJxIPMzahAjCwHK6wltZ2C@QLMagsayLaKq88UEWIjIHWrhVv7CQbfeFk@C4uElSXzGvGwri8iRJck2KSYiso1GDgenz1MPBawlNHXza8DWIOcRJFQURRGKGqXD56n6C/u5y/T1QqAMiTCUwS7Ge3ZXeVq8X9rJTOe@Mk71dgRiYZPvqTOUoTGFMchgdRDTzRbx2S8XHLRxcyeeJhtintP2AbOGY4A66TY8tOC7UEvqXk54XGfC8yMwn1G2NpHOpB0qLjikJPLzgYU7HRVucV17wWVWMITSRbXY@uYL7kxUcrTzERwXoT5Gct3I8oYZrW@O2TQYy0QdFqpFjXJDT8mdYzWNPEPe0FBsuw4LHUfVk/@j502@g093Y2FBFHz0a5w9bLU6qhv04x0x7b8P@YMawJZNEA9G4eE3Xq@NdhkvnjnxLlnBhDcoAXowRsJ9o46qQZRF5PtV2IR6HjVBU4LoYNwNzQiqhqmNil20LuvpAEMtXVkyBJFBvgd5JGq2pOCcL3IF3bFWr1H1Vq7gZqVoVvRhWTbDCrf4ytpQaeH26RI6br72SJDpPyvaP2MsnO2fs7EmJHbzY@5J9c/SCvdx5fobnMY9f7D493GPwLT0/LbHxjAJ@0KQ/DiiBrvtW3erWQGRn0uk1Rpj33N6Iyx1lT@X@p2aXPXHrFq5HbXtm93Gbv@iO5Rd5rBIMR0fiPmTIaNf2fX4dVh3QkXLToENZuH@dAWwNxrRdHPN23YbdtAFWwrFvz7a84AAR69hQgyBvgwOASa4k4fUCtBWIrpaiW8HwWimAx0UaQGN642vMbI9HsBo6E4QLP59MwbPSybNTtvN8n@0dPd8/PDs8en7KDo5O4PX4m8PnnwM9D0/PTg53X2AQAT472j88ONzbIQ@egbTO8MQt3RO2KAs6ghNV6he4xE2XQoZv0VlnAAMNnl2ZdDzNY/GBg9LHNjv2O6sRz0t48Qg/EkdrAiy89otZb3EpM1jzpf0E8guPrs5YTrNtSg0aSxHaW140V@j20IgxLjx0RwyvULHydBBWIff4ahbalNOwLSbv4Z4TnPvm52WpLQeoIaElwI2ogg0oBUYWwePx5DahLEJq9Y6LZp14anxToHjBqI@DrSN5iSgm9r4gUtw6f@jgfJCRDz2A78EjI5L1@xyArYYeHICtcQ9URQ9xLwjLCoiBfzRA8czWucebbu@A1n/ZRuixa9IodlPkidcbVanJxpfN2t1eh2y681keuqrF9Oq2TVE8gkeb6J1OcF9azQKWB5kobrfBvWoAKYOwaeJSg9jG5gyoYUPoAC9W99pm0/eYUlB1doabfSzH5sbyWx3T4VuaxltxiPfYJlpDKIjd1nZohb7Bb3omBsSbISbzEcbbF1qhdd94EHP3Voqm2PNIN5kEW8ruysDurQz8KmgAkTYx0qlTT0VHFRGN2xSsrHgucCTO236IwgM7NwZ1ayJCcJvdG/vdO1UQOTkxTgr2HVLuoIrw4r8kX7Nsun1o4yRWu3i2A6Vgve32fJvXoTJZgvFdRACNHRuk9rpQnEiN7h@cStFxnUiiNeDiOanWgCnvkypxPF8kD8VX0NbDy5BoHx1mx6y5l1Zk7SyJi0hXFk6/gCLML3LD3oau5RT6pzSWHR/ocr3NQnF/91z78DqJpty5WODXFwWbCPllfF1MC5oHrfPRBsQ@6l2ipQX3AXiDGsYWe@qEtMRWHiCDcWDbhnHd42o@DOPbh2/749mSaX/yfP@@wGNpKJm4RB54bWUs3ZKsHCSZpDgVJvZ6RGQnZBZkvRL4JAlnKK8f40ERrIU8UMRBOULXaE7a4RciJChdbdAEySJu2hHVHeJXWZG2TgSKJH2UaH2kXim7hURRTY13jrAIOZVARCcDzHgRz3j/CfVXt9DtL0YH8vv@6DYX5o53D5@EbX8htk/Km5aYj4t3SxFc90f7YQFa3rn9Smih7Mn5iHkneRtbyOkhcyaXY@Hu2MUpvr5Vd9T2AA32vTiDEiKNpDZwaIk6sL2o8AhqFM1YITo92y@dnDCZj08gLsg9HDI0hBhE3Ev8mgK@e9Z2SNjpodIUDpZD5Snwmdi6Fh75WNCYZxJvjqgQOkhS0CMUFpOXApLUEz0LqRC0m54EYkC5ydxdBzLIKwvEN2hsE4RXbKyGhQWUZhYzxjsf24tu6hZ0S3LdOLonn3ZM874br/fpj6KIopt/zBaeFJldfy@5fpwL0uEKlvV2QAVugCaNN1zq7BQS7gGgrk/W4IJqCaoUN81zBTsW0A53eKUnNey/O0MRI3ElnOvCEbEulGORNa4fLwdqDu08xG7AxC2dIpDvUIaAQMSTz3a0QtVxp6dMdkGgZOLFM4@jXAHRKzf58K5KZdxPFkKFPNrWlik35SCXFZydFbjz84E@w73N69PiYTopkLYLk9L@fpLivcRESgHNZxYmCATM69ns6l24p0sRRNf@rrh5HzItP/1uD8b3Y5TeyKPpfeDcw@fJIHzMAAtIx7fKBw1mKiKoOjP6lImyU2cUzR/khc8LQWbQnGm9jdfsTKaqsuFU3mZj5z1SFDuB3CpDpAmHBeWt5hb1bxYnhwL5zvSWPj093tgQCPcI3vwyPFwXsRkS8cJjopN@Vr/vEBg/ltR18fgYnUZaeGaODs3xDa28MBhIy2zRAjTFISO@rTYZTDFQIjSrqOO1XDipl5@e1dOMfLSEB4dPS2yFzGw1J6Yg5b6sRkTOku0sygCJXpqOwF6DjuJ95uXgC3lIBiiBTHQoTyHaqHfmjSgCynKZ7MSLbZ9CpBrTld706qaDBiySMt1o@xAi0uRr6ehAnTWhns5PxIfMeT1HgVhJWdNligp@OI@LmCZR8NpE/0g/JaGddLFBcsElnmbK2Eyvb0lUOifpJ7vlrUpypV6QGfS5ptP1Bv2rxkXLbV82WYf13tSG9dG7t4xl1xge8c085AYFjfUCnm5VGN47tMm20sSwIoOPyDjiucwYWfLAs9pxNh5@55fQ1h18aKycwxMQU1zKVroBF@JJOb/QLa9XCk4hne@WnUoez@r5iYKfMBIKejyEzhNEC1@QL/sV7Ep/GZ1ttZxL1h/URjBKCs9@MDr7gf07znCJPds0X07bjKUHuFkNz5DojnWlhBcUI2dKqP9ID@gQj4GnvWm6GGdbGjbkAKifBGXVG9LvSJUepPVBz3cpRCSkIQux9/Z76UFw6ihNEwYAUrYrQXa2Cc8YRsF1H@474ruhNYNrYwYedVQjKMoYk6SdfC7LeAQQMyqOXpUrkqdbZr2NmcCr6N5TNLa9ze@ovoFgmqTDnRpmnw4@pCvoxPUNePRoMQGTIMXco@MbEhQf3w10cB@agvLpvAttdJdIEcQQ3MbNruk4EsXfBgJwwj/gKpUuZjCFYgV6Ij/qR3MHaC5tclyPqwh4CpJXygMsLOLm6RXGyGnHN9EIkxVkAv8HV0hOTiv4iBJoBr3dKkYIr3JwIgktQ4s3D2lJVUpBRXx0xtGUSDQtiBYAR0jx4E5q4EQWjH6eWdB8RmzP6nQg05wWD8bkQCcdxxXpJ8L0vTKmWQkzz8O1W@HaRLjOw3mmxlA69N9joFwUSI5dj@FumDwGS95Kq8BIN9Ghpus6aBxj2PwiWE/33ao9Bi6GVcm5MgzYngjQIiGvZtQ@D1maiBMyeBhe5uGCvzOi5sNcTsA@nkwfn5KoIIv2xoqtJFNcqjt25xHvnMIQZDOZ4aXnPDrWN7Edb5TiyKQQJ6Cg4TQ@NdtiYYwlYQQSh9qMXNx@LOtCmXikTGeDHzq81bBmtJEIlSjNBBFuSOcLIR0KXoqgIJzIaCxoucUg8khEHkXQItRSkCw/tHirgUPRppt4AY8xvsefoLFPZi6Ai80OfMBzPuSF54eRJwlEQndJnk2mSWmCxz64pyjUgl5knPZoGuNsIfE8MskbpmnxI9NNnOVeCuVEVFAEkuIW3cMQQekxgBGw77wqxMAb6ZepFelzE1ToXscash0cRZh0mkqaOI/uW57vof0itNgIw/Ner4OLiqTYXdGJZ2GbI5PF1ZQxxsgymi4d4sYdDp9Elzg/DpF0doSYr3D/xzjAG7Ra/IZzhpaLQLTihIrt69KOM@LzFdBmVjP8VLjFBh5fFIXBfCuaCV5zvPXQrex477cugS7mgZYj8aI2efsW0@V4LAQtUkGXlpOk7wzs@sXe57hcu2GkV40IyS7Fam9aX10bH5QCIgUBmTSoq1ljTZIiS791vvSrIcIke4od/VfAm9YlXsMq7UCPQYAeKKee1b@0GroknVjhGi/iRVbGhUc8Nu0O@nU@dwO6FV7fiqd9vSRf7QIOwyf2z3w1uE5LYUkJ16TGi8l0ZX0DCRgcKGm6uPhL6xF4qp/TAyN1LR@IsqKyySzR0rLIC@kuXZxnAmqY4iZ2sfQQksFxfbsONUMTVVIHUPFVjnFi/LLpSE4gvXrHxEO@@qwM4OmXMQWCDAQrRYvyIIk18U/KQ3DFfLCEbgY1kwLp51JbgeZu9W2QvmMCU61QtEjeoYLPnhyestOjg7OXOyclBu7jk6OvDvdL@2z3G1rCxnVwMmnKnhw9BekSLpbzRfEj8JB3TiGmTAHSzvNvWOnr45PS6Sk7OmGHz46fHgI2QH@y8/zssHSaZIfP956@2KfFdcDAnh@dsaeHzw7PAOzsKEmpBtGkcTx2dMCelU72nsDrzu7h08OzbyjFg8Oz55gYLtrvsOOdk7PDvRdPd07Y8YuT46PTEsOCSfuHp3tPdw6flfZ1SB/SZKWvSs/P2OmTnadPpwp69PJ56YTRHoBIKXdLkMudXRiqYkpUzv3Dk9LeGRZo7NoD4kEGnybZ6XFp7xAdpa9LUJydk2@SAulp6TsvAAgC2f7Os53PoXCScgdVoF72XpyUnmGmgRKnL3ZPzw7PXpyV2OdHR/tE69PSyVeHe6XTPJOeHp0SwV6clpIMb8ShpAEHUAvCwb374vSQ6Hb4/Az6jBfHuJ1BhUp@CYSBXO5A1H0iMO5ywNICkY5OvkGsSAeqgCR7@aQE/idIU6LWDlIBN0zsnUXBIEEg4lm0mOx56fOnh5@Xnu@VMPgI0bw8PC2pUGGHpwhwiPstvgHWgURfUKmxniBf3AnMKgWcm6TqZIcHbGf/q0PMuYAGDjg9FNxCZNt7ImgObTklRSZLbBfnBsxudAKledvr0kLThLdnXmbPxYQGjvaO9kug8XH7WfLY/wV0OptTho@iYdDRhIHwOmFgpmHVBq2q7TRdPCoaRuPzG12vlcRLAlQYnbNzacE9EWIahSLEYtXqVztVGOeeVqtq8j4xJ7JxVwwxyb0IShVl7LjceAPO7@RynOzbE4QqPhTLmLQND5cXEJIT/yHf2GZ2LZWlUg1LRMMz@Ig4mCHy@KJIGxdKQDLSUUY0mz9OkiYg6N0W3EARlQC9Xq/iLCjueyQg14Mf5/34hfcNEQ8QznxWK5XCMSxlw35nBcnwRMiyAf0IwwJ2k5LUPcu6aCnpaHI45NdbrttQVDWIQ7A@DANbinpH9JrVmoquTcenzNKisrCH7gXDbtJgwtVlQTIm6kXvU8kU/Kn69FCD3HDTDTgnSknRVLSYm1Qe8ui43yjJhIUKPDxBlYwq37Odrw9f4mAunVnLT/k/Cf1528LdgGhVFfq7MsWr0ONJhQNAAyOTGkASWxi6SKUicYLdJP9fe0@23bax5LP5FTBoiwDFXbspKJZs68aZOLkTO4tHUiiQBCkmFIkAoEVa0Zwz8zA/MB8wnzIP8yn3Q2Zq60aDAi1lmST3nuScWCDQS3V1dXVVdy268BUUvMBCFDCetuqLgLZ1QAnIsTN/bPaJm3E0mpvQAxv@yxeHr46@PD4GzonQbu5u7Wy3CzpI1jcV/vsW@6GIohQjLIRtHMQ0@mSskmcg99BKMQJEp@RPBFyvY0EMwa0mjV5iuAZtlZG1U0I@hsONMYfEBA3w7ADxYFsUR@NhQdFr7soUAnAyQ3VxNJf@nCR8H0QlogExVRkvaNbm@A@2rZe/WuJ6QEJAQmIUjxUoF5QL4nv2sTIEJd2GwuxgkZqt6JiDrmkc0EkXWcei7yz9Eto2ZjFmQ0VcrzTtVBOAeLgMhaWsJia8sv9K4ULknJdifcGbb4Te4PGthKOj4HR@nBwmrwGNx7omHkenZ84y6BNp@ezAgylaW9M97Vt4mO8KULT25NRYx/cwVgOBcoYmg5611HBbhwNZ7pLsW5@WXOuaKRVjcGA7baFY@Q2UmzccaaWtwoDIbxVcwuK2dKwSxtqV7qOgirzV4SgUOjNo@kX4oPZ/R5zktL8PCie0nmLLCNl3L0xSq4wr0F4JKaMrdZ9gXGKk2DRfvU2buTEn5kIPTC5p5uw9AyiQ2VmoF28pSOHAyUEAEjmea5jrVxucXfigOT21XamO1yGT3mXoWLJXqK3iVrtnFZK5KuoCBX@4lssHTUZ3n0JF6ynbyCWicAEX6y6sx7HNbaw3XRW7o16mQw@9yok0L9gQdZmcGrK01OKXMEnGLtPX0Y5AFL1ZeSNXtowolhmGL7dabtuMbmkOWNAGfR4goLnjRgt8NsXNRkvkeOBvKIIdRqJGnRm3Igk31yWjy3GA7Tzu08kIZrdMrnC7GHPrFGYvbc1yHpNRCHaSWhimMQKR@bo1wDptslcaejqmRHrV0H854UjrAR9xqRI1DuYhEJqu8TXrlb9AmMf3G7eddr6OaD3I9v9yQqEHewnvlOE0Js0dekFN/3GcYkSZ4cA@lGJJ7C9tRaOjq@poDn@or6qMXAVxBJ2BAkzmCf03KxUCii@ZvSG17NOJPkR6whuZ91iJL/jEa1c/vcUnOWf2YFAAHLzB61QRgxBklJvwCu/2aiP4MDbc16Mg6pvHcrCb9v0QT4BI/J5OaNtVp1cSQa7nJ3GwACm0Vx/N69RGx/lkejHpPJuO/eFoOvJBV8AY2nNegPi4oEeM/zmMplcxZSKhD32jUH@RPnMEE47ohb/11VjbiPIUJ0HomDfiSbQ4vOBABHR4i2ZmluaZFEQ1XA63petsbqWVClkPR7L4arrtlXU3mnmV@fIYG5BldbB0Wc9eigm5vhjuje1bBbofKmDA2LWqlu@usAnLQLwHKKKbgAzECphbN@DmIFA7WAnxSX9e6VM4uwhD@QTPA8zlETv0uuJjTkLg9B/hpfQTq7nbMKryQf4cQ9rhw2I1uls7vzP0AMAvAL@5kUcteYRAAX0HKp5PzDKzxKUEWHQCrgpqAqAkT6PREBTbcabRzny51eznxSpskJEJbM0Sse0WVeKKdED4xrxVTgdYTmfhWj/@aJWskkuRIXBHPEycxmqCDe6y0KTFj/eIfHiDjOmZtOwYQK9CVQ@whAnplgw4TZA5Cu/dK6bVuu@sLSHQyzNqMjIEOLbaL8nHQWQevFmZRsCM7SXsibVBKU6mYeme2FvJO3KDfOXhuue6d5qaMrF58/VWuU@o9Rb4uGgXluFZIposxsioCWgIVSh61mS@jMS518H15nUWd@BhFc5SEx29qej57vPax03xHdqMqo1GLymCHeNdtvX7kw4MvLOag0ibLOJ3iGN0kGV0FvxoNLWEJo2l@2OIqE9gX8JHHzCH/fYBd@b8rETqsj2Wip6pPmXiJSI@MdQ3ugUCXwoHeP@Pgcj4ikQzKY5qHjzBwK50m9SsdjFeLX7gBtFZJaimZyF8iphO1hIdUTz5gdNBg5UmciJ4OjAv2XWYeI0wiuMuBwxy6d5ZVJtnbW5prlsCWZZKfagl5dEMP086c2rlFipgieegQo/oFm@6uP@ofulYoBy0wLXps9iSNio4GNdaB2jgH/NTZ44ycNqV1MysqOxC6BBrgLUAashwHLD2hNLfKGKKxwt2WUYg2vNrB/@sSw0MAL3d0NjGKvP@Aou4gm5eba5VPeAqKUHxb0S/LEUWdUldggYChhjqe01oASNkEvR4ME3BXUzKywAqcwQVvSYuS3hJATZTk8Kc74hUKbC5ZZRo5JXYM9uo5jYCgkV@mRQQkFnyi6StwEaXC4tRYid/PGkJEIgV7TPGYSpkVrI41DPHCIRHglZzlJOmVWkIBdPHzS0381HTN33daxhfG8tfAT8awpNqc/nrbiPzNdNtq5WtmqkJ@HDNXjMfARWuCbDmCr/sP3J@MKNna7NEQ8nISBliCjxBVeoK9bbad7G1T26/SsZQ7Zm@x0r96nBSjkx87w/H8rYkUnz7lw9W2UYqQCS4PAU@U94UDuuDJLDauNPjqFDRVaHctAe8UmmnA@urN8fHmbii3YUydbkMoq1Go4E03DXDqCsrXjy/GE3r2dL1wWw8rodXn0RfdevE@jHX8ziePlEKdAAzAmsirk2jIacSQBigKJauiqckqvqzwcCM2Y@XZDh3MGtcUtztLdp/Rtrs4qs3dMBDTcr@eo4DxPGdW3rxXfksZ0or6iYEaqNR6jtbXeAAevDFAC2B9WUJNYZ8WdnTwLblegfXuIFgKgyaLAqE616nBrL2x8F4PK1YX0@jcR9d0R/cLFc4PjYrNLgIXnKR@@gspoCnFSt4NxobjqtYxCR1bE7tSyoxgYowjlHWvwiGL@ahY598a8OuAkNex2GuY6TjimUPbVfCjt@jWaZDAPtepS/90OkRnpYLw04vCzh9Aog2mpVc1SdTxKUUI4Kzu0sjUvPBrVE0ABi6S6KAiopO00sjWVFcI9c@nTcHiMMGtyEwYVCP@9VAX6bfjyu@SwaD@zFFCijPE/ubM0Q6kaYVKMsP8InxmP@pCsv6eCliBcs3mPbhNt/BCh2sUCg87nk/XDmHh4fWo3B93To8PIKHatU6PDq0nuOLoyPrOfw@wt9rXmtrq80897l7DS@P1Msb6wjaoAPO9d5F9Bx@wjcPHZPQXhin@FHde1RpP@p4@wftuH5yeIR@4/D0t3/7j7/9@3/WD@XHf@GPI/px8q0uVKvV6o9614/Wbtr4@@T5WelR9@RReFYatpHKkN1/GcX@2DcMGGu9wh1OOv3xqLvKcUdbcIxishZEiz0H/vE80MB@/JGfTpP0MUofMSxnWt0fhxc@VbeohQOvdFhaW4Onfa/0LyU6O5H3vn7/Ht5bLvJy8tsn1GLqGevw9bOXL83I18j1SXofBBimBVMnyrXJaBKPYFDnRZVzrnpi1WrWWdU61@ChqUGHC2ZBZDWTgflXAVKNjuxC6P5U1Aa8GKWjbz6R53uSy3hI8p06Ouf8W75oKo/7T/hSh9pYB4aH5dtsLi2ulzh8ABdvYbzqSXN766xaLBYLOidXp0dsjnoLqS@do0ld49IdDHsChbBkYOyc@h1xAQ0iMopFyti01uPMYs4EVWvSmFjhLpYMeR7Pm2ggBc3m@ISb/flRxkKFj7JgWfGMHAFQNljc90oJACAPr31iXBYnm43DoDcaLPS1OyZFSHuHvRK9tsrW4JbTlmVHXVvG9XCQNggIQSmAwsVgo8sNMvKmUHZE3I7HqH6DuHGbqM4l/rS1SROsjVLC6XgxHENnDpnzxFfAnQDzrkzWeKK8ubAHrtkNBpjrnFc0T1hqTopwdwM8ipj0QMHsY4qiMYaFYoGPryApICKsB5RwJEXZAL0RnPGEjVimA3iEDR8duTgdG5HhOm6pQlCo1KJyrFKcCR8oh65rhVwSsQq/0wtgIg86giR9WHKtZa4CQ1dq4tt9obQQs8uhIi3hKV1ZSTatFX0BC1LlJV6Q4eUYIAVL1iidFbCGhXU@npzr8fOVWowZ8ej@jBPOUTctviMHjqW7UR7b1B2bo9t8uErJryZ@IugNp3E86gKykoWaJorCx/brEbR6WipwZ0IteFGHCMZX5VCvKHN8ipSCeUgu4gzvAzzanSgqyBTEa0W8E@O74WLmpngynVSJ5XaDZNRjIz7u/aHixSFe05L1PgG2uiNQHviiUk0w9XCqAtzIHSVNddoO4Qnt5XH9X2jR2yecyTGvsGjxXQCANHHo2TlNkZS2qCmBGsgiRWAkE2TB4IMMYY6D4SjJ1KlIEAC2fOZR3CjU4yI/R4BN7C5hFm31aVV2jX3mXPCtzAOQ8apvwGh3XfG/zaM9NRjc1Tj3oa7JQyKXrt3b9KH5kQLHhBpWMKAPl28lO0O0ueJeR3HMMJpkP0uqVjoLH@yBGhcQmV@UyceEGhBusYyT6glgo7WEDWCnS8sg5cKNTPMGASNxmzs58agl9PJ0sUhwi3krelGQIhHcFLRXyfX/d7@ZqexG6CILiw9KIR3AHp2aOehQDstN5q7Aq0AJ6hKfDVhjNMOgaGw@ITsKRlEZ8SI1OtVwLHWlhi4zXCVJKaQQHfDzpGTO5VJVNd609lm2drXEXkXXyrfIMSSd0BWXI/n6QFLRb2@pdtlpiK7e6NeN8m4S5yBtM6FmR1BO26s/QPSgFQal@dGTc5NHGkqHV1xejVkkCxAuM41TW3RFI@VMS5QcJLGtwuEsmb5Mfn2ZnsIby12ffkkZP0Eu8EEMFhHBd@vyBI9oAev@WmoB8oERMAK2ofLjAJ4LBZY8RMO0X8XDo@ncaVRO7VO70tzec23Sk7UcVuzFoBkVewEH7MKsgaJ7UmBAOtd@FzALj7qjfj@YqHCgUFV605860uwJHudfa3YXc5JVm5h4YBu8PK7CJNILwTU9h5E/vPTp8bPpm8hfvIRNiH5@PuH5fI3tfQGbEaYFoi9f8Bo97IOoYd@gnpzSxL2GSC5LPkg@vYREAw4GZ4gLOQgIbiGA@9Tjj7ODNdBgjp/PLrT0TPsmTOo5SygxG/Ke88XJeYFzzl5iUtQOvwPadIyktPJIn5YyJYuMgB@UjZnxlmuwqD/Gm55gkrmHUNFrhfA4czHXqlhjINCGUrk@PJQp2@Sea@jjc1Fskt5F53I2TkYyslvDUuPCSsvpd0mdVBmTV6TgpSPDZdwZ48B2T0awSlNdhhhVigVRwlQrhv6o0E3jp2PHVGgQVYUjT7Q2iT4aN@0PzA1L9wdK1cDAEMaFjVJOcZwFQ92A2u1Cus9aetQPM8oHwgFIQTDKIeU@JtZ8Y84xzjCGriBmoif3t9DZ/56VXH5Dtw0plpReit6vIDIwD0t1fbJsr1gNucQ2tFqgFE5@Pb0MRLMVdcJQXo3EZRzP8XdXWO/Q3DLSn4EqZTlsyi4PMwstIxwqk00DnVqIoZ3ZnAUaqymMmJIEsZxQfPMZz9LSDTtG57INVkqgJMO8LGQriUmPNIe9QRO3Ns@KFiNufXKV9KYlICoKNNVXTFV2t3Rjk6TXeKqX7mAK1qxMaYrsVrqBpjJrjhKuyeBORAW3EdX8eYhiuPLwxF9@NTRlEZDF0k2hkEe@mnWIaZa51rUXyy2@RIh7qAXhpTZyBN3uGOPWpYAtN4dJ40Wy31PCcNk6HAJbzMrCbGHtp@9Y62EFMl7yWtYHcWwVP4swrmsRpKsC/I8xdoFLXeKBTuYEBETWekEXIh8lxAbhW59GiNe8VS@6BbEZqhc5U01zp@lSJ/foCZ1Af4F4z2wQr2IGtxywcEMhkaNsdcSJ7e7dj/a6FcfSmfHlHkkDR04PpZk9l8MQjcnvOqWuFyWagmNB85Zr/cwDajorafEehOc89WLhAYDAkgaGdYPOqPa6HPDGAQxDB4Xk49zUDIv1Q3XQ/Uc6/1Y4VrYKQgFaQGgo6QDlM8pCzBMsEgI5U9ICLT2OS4Bq7cqR20sqqpG4SKjNULLawZuyVeceCOlZoV06ttIknlFinCrmnpqqEyKrmFvNcjDKJZ5m0NVR0MODcH1KFbvGebAcO9ShbUkKDWCxs55uMsOuzOGsrVkCGx1ZL8kYuYp@BlEMRwYZpxNmzsukC0wIXxLiZUuBZaKlvjD3/IELSIl0da7lCyLIXlM5JD2hqad4n0005vOxQ1U/hB9yhpguObkQToij6vAjKTSFn4rQZXzeQaR0oPf3Q6U/aSbuS6qSOnoVLfJevNPkvdjcexZxHU8bcPfBv6Me@5qSc2O6/1hl0wH4Ae@/dEwB/zCBkr9Coh3ZgdvHiSvprh@kel0tTjqcuVuzX9TjxOSu34ftGJgteTZVQE9MyAbJMvCsDGzJyf0nbZhKSefuhRWCiomgLGtmUjvVyyxSzAz1V3nGE6YG4kr8AJoj8yLyJsSrq2mPfdNhg8LvA/JMJ722yWoRKkRc8QR/iovfgwFHyhvISuYRWOWOdCtjEHhoECxjHUV@ci8RK72SY4N9nbx@mQ7jWsF6@dNFsvvIZeV7y2XFMp1pl1PxrFwMQbbY@Jlt/LZyWnpAC@3YGnIbFyod4JPKASiGCRqjhXF6mC9cy7xy@/li35/iyx91Yyj/4cWXskZ/LyvElFMhppcrxKQFpFYPD96oni5P7AGW7YQ05LKIPdzfNNsfrBvV3zS3P04GbqXlpPKUusXXOd0mV1OpoQlVOqTzx9yOkNfymj63ZW2fW87tBc3znW7DG39uw//Y23Bd4wIDXt6x0xhT/@fc/yPMPYZQHO82dhudX@3eV7@zTcKyl@5bLct@aDUPPto5nT9vnM73Nj//oZgUD1r1ryP4mxR/KG7vFvkRHuDXhvr1rnhQ3Mdi2zfFRd3zPHiUVg6PoZWDT3SbWGqxD/8cbKl2txfFg6pH1X8sHmzDQ7PVAkhO5y/2Tue7Dfzfbv@RxA/zdkULH6taDSmuimwIfBcoJvKklk/jtMlnxu7wEklAqePZA1Lc@aHRKgGMxjPz1m5DZBUgII7/8C6QFFCXAabu0sdTFMMkoTga7HGh4j@IrR5XghWgu3DhD3VBu72IXmnMCRVuAqWEFGjr/HFtG6@uzyUMhQZAB54gMZNNuUG9cKhjDLGFfw8aH9k6MMUTW@JW2KbFv9xtyq64K7vi/xatcJFcTCetnMDqResZTFcSWN/FDEs8GYVhkLDEPwwmAWzJeJg@mqKgg5neepgXbzz6ns3/nqjGrR411Pku7rBvDjdUCxeW/egprKzRJWlF72FVqme8H9veVL@AcWPOMPSTUd41w1FyMetSTPw30eJl8jlFoqhjXO2Eo1LUQZbr1i99NBygSPIxkBiUAHYQzSZ1yi0GAhv6ymD490v/ewAN85nC0PodKIaH/d87lDw0DkJycZkPBjZl6gnG/ddB6Ec@R01Dq/mZPwxeYmAYmIz4wkblqWh9Rs41iRkdVytLhHGQwyUlU5UjWBHvj0vK/ZNQa1nobkwZY2z0UxcmRLzbrpHXBNSy2bWAslQPptMkLc9e47oC/czWoJhgMEnsGoKXg@mIgJvj@NcVEOuWJS8IjvSndJq@oI4ImsgaYSYHHFUwmV0S7ejMqifNJ2cSN81rGhmuyeJ194lkNbdtRChOkxw2N3fxy4xtL@lesiChA/Q4QLBmSKAgT8iMbgsvQVOI42n3O4r7g1wJFiTSX019k2VPZvTwiIfdk2DoE6@46o4SKtAfxVQAa9aH70F2ZxRVMqTanQ3jGq8FcqwYxfEs2NrZ3SSAaMdXRfvTXqZoqw4tR360qBNwF8nlWI9iL7mwxsG7YCzWKwQ2RZTlRUl0hkm1/NmYzFq2XSIdQGVmpIAFZ6/C756/OP708M2L5xUQU7aweExuSbqsYyCXP6/T98EYIzUwGWEVXr617vYmE7kTV0pP8USOQX9qon3dBFg1EMc13ANGoVPyqJrYWXDDVohq@2RY0dfhV9Poex24GJcbgjKjbAe2Qq5a@cUiunTF2FcRSTAT2ADq4MCU53Y0BsZzq9BKXgEYEO7WSYAix8g/kXLt/YfVql5TT@ipCoy1Wj3gQxb72XgEimfpi9kkw21LtHZ8qwRMDq//mbU9LBFfqNlt68JDPb7d8xpt7bf3zpm51zor8gChcBhxb6ZHCzV/zkw802xAiEtWzspl8n/@u@S2b9IgOmMncTH6v/XeU8GLa8zUX3C6VKcU92CyEqj2vpYE8@QZR5v0krau0J32F5L2/hlo1X3nvdlH6LjXsFevr/c8b8O9hi6jEKNQhsAMgzfQotvGd4PMO@0iVj89nWAO5DK67n3z6tOPYcrRTiyIk5Nvz8qP6pVSyXXbOATfI/@@55@/@iue8kdujU77j6PppeAl8nUnNZjty/ikcUbQV2wcWh1XIXDOYZDI6OOjxRt/@BlIS07JBxSgWRI5xsGkjPZ98S9ro20SylyYH8TEkWdnJ9d2r4celbqIgkGbzypuYu@dM3TbCfy5MLvYgi68VotaT6CSh1ZNS1gfTWC3/vjNq0@90r5vYatezqoorXc1cQChEME4@OoQMyJlSAe4ClFVwt56RDDw33rJPsiOZb/uH5TaNzcr4fmUY7qC8FNKCbjvzCpCcZF3e0rbUUoFizDw8AVvbX958cauQF0MwYIvJ7i9LYhpsROrp/pgckNOQVvg4jWW8bzNtTV6h1Vmsee1Gg0XI6LcQGsxpjCHZnlhRe2byPf6jkakH45yEva0aq06O7LE9eZ2q7G189E0gi3Cw5zoazGwEA@1lnejZLEGsmHgqeQ/ayAnw27qPdws734@Ovrnb/Zebz93et1PmnbF/i4ms/0oNAGI/Ksai0XAYyOJ90pAoOdiz6@H/vfT@ma/0QPJs7nTD3a2gt3Gxm5vK9jY6@7t7fUGm7vd/t6Ov7PV69Yx3jhVqV2OJiAl2Uz@2O3gft2uEsx2W429waDZ3N7pb@0N9lqNjY3N7u5Wv7G5Odht@hsb2/3Wbnev@2GpLYWnAAxW8V3cO5Y58OPVwl3hFm@X2u7/AQ)

Internet Explorer 11 automatically blocks JavaScript in local files and displays a prompt to enable it, so there is no need to disable JS in IE11.

To separate IE11 special media query is used (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173106/apply-style-only-on-ie/41714276#41714276)):

```html
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
```

Space before `(` is mandatory.

I noticed that sometimes colon doesn't need to be commented out in psPILOT (eg. line 41), so I removed `//` from line 28.

Answer (score 2):

## 262. HTML+JavaScript (IE11), 12160 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}['4o'6o@.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<- ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtPsPsPsMbMbMb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWww⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;pppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:257</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #ata=",_"[ 4];t}?1<&&1$/PLconsPrerslo/  \~-<V->8;rextnu U9583>Ehar51 Cr=B$f 16ger[d 2FAC]ngt.putsle._>dmint 22afbont:2: 6  l{ $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;{-W-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a )where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,0,0,0,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id` ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))-(-q?6+50+z));q _=r$(d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$f 0$f 2 64;f=(^);instance Num();  (!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<"Z>"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};] ppppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Q222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2qghUAQUS/AAIsPkB3ua93U0Oyb5974BodAEoAHUJVOGiCiTQbHbMjDdmNZbCK49nHaPRWnckW15p7QhrHeuVHJbCEdKrQ@En/YCWXzYUG5p/MHvOyaxCAQRA9kiK2CJRlZ8nM0@ePHny62TN9Nq//GUMH3bidkatjusz3/J81ujbV1ZfZ3sj9sS0vWxmVZIw1G6/Nehaju/lpBgzGHOsa3bk1O0GuDHfvbQc@63VB78MY72@2@qbXea3TR8sNsRiB1bnXfedz@put2s6DQ9CrjJ2YoJnc1C/ZGbN8/tm3bddB7zWGHvpdMxurWEyCGH1e33LJ/BZBiDqlxRn0medsedu37Mw@brleS46bjC2bXV7/qgIlk0IYfZt99nui0@nIm8x9qkJOet1rOFUXow0e2Vb/cZUDMNgX5wfHk67Ztjnmuuww7v5M1bZy75ndsxp@Gtsd@C7R/60e5bttizHZBl9S89Me66zvb55J8oG61tmo2l3LN126kxjbavTs/oMXVjT7UOV@VZnM72Zru6OY@p1jLs59pwCWwgeZvZbHni6VxYYLaiJnm01WLPvdpnpeNeQkrGVHodHsFuT5FCHDAKhsa89iN2wmOfYvZ7lc08ortUnb0iZdWznUuLUd9J3G4O67bQgnAV47Q18KpMn1SFakfUEDetoYDHCAg8GWThzu1a0LjwgXsi117PqdtOuc@RYQ99yPCivpzMb6u7a7nRYw@pAhDH0epJ5Lht4Eadax2zrdV1C5GIqrHvZYTar93qMe0ExIEuH6U1mdd2vbfYW/Dttjw17XebZXfD2626zaVnsrdVrQ3TWbUgNV2Lw1HtTJQttyxaEcSwo3f7JV4A3H9HpNCFrDVaLhIN8UJ6pxKbjAvr6zDG7nBrqvRGVHsCEMZquq6N7w7U8J@6za7d/yWpW3cRiY2Ke1Wqagw6kaDexOoAObI91XfhCJToMsgWRfcQFwsbEpJkFwWSC6rV60DCxel0kF6jroJav@ybQR98T9ejbXaAO2497zDI9GzkWRPEsp0GU0Qt5mQuljVY6u7Kh4QEqBn2C7Vl9In2Cy7AUANIMaVW57ts@UASWYpedWGafnfctS@V0anl1s4dUGk0SEnMxBR8LohNhbm/HS8eHcSBQHkM3e0CQ/dXz73wmmUwvsOVqHn4FWc5LpRcH7Gb5As2cZwIR9/qKqbLCe@alLi4s@A2NWqrVv5UAqgRY6bCU2/NTptaDDGo@ZDBlohFN2lVG73UiCbPtqTqINBseqgG1AUyAfZGkktUH/T5y9zFSzUsodMd1WoBPKGx/4PAqX09DFQD9Nbwks64spAFeR@41Yfi8DRQC/xA0wll4h0MIhS4HmqLAaJCu53YGFA5iej62R8AKREWIR032BWuadgejgD@C4rnuWx4QJ8YZOA2s@a7tWA2dBdkgrtOHtngFyZkAlBygNXQjvIUyBYGhIlwqKnp9@M3fbrRaAGe3Xnf7DUGuXwCx16lrNCmz0LkxJFjXMTuULQiXxNR5dEjgyuzYDeJypjMSSVAmKNVrd9BpMGqo1zY0ubYJzNYCBlH3LU7k7sCHPCZZ17zkHNHmlAsF75o1qFhKgNKmYmvsyT7UUh2aOdGM1h34zU2m9Uos7qVeKzs5ZWfpwoLMqbq6spxKtfJAcPoKOYEtvohyvtid6Co83/RcuyH1Rn7bdTJMqzO5XnB7lqPEJ2DEk/F@La7qyKkVNW8X6nrTdhpKfBtosQgJx9V8vVAv27lKfip6NEkAc41gsLlaSl2VkdVQo7hKdUG40IGTfaEJU8TP9aqIcvTWI86ImGm3K@4QI9EF6dJFAgE@pHsdy@opad1QkU1guJnlRo9ZJZ2CIQqcsyuJeCyeiBadIEBJJwqKjfXcdpFtdXptlDcAKY7XA57bR9qtm0A9HnZqPoh0SVYjuqaeEDgL8cRrKw5cuwaMNKAjapK8yWF8DRmlgDBuQpMt2WpEGjIwAWjLvneHG3dclA4oT9jzAOtwMFGzBVUDkXlBdnlBeErkMlmkSwcYCkKrWWxTq9nQCLC5AU8XNB8pGwRfzfAwAI03kgjv6Zoj7NW4aDBuMNinmawL7KE/YnULeQ4wH4t3KJjIgNqfB3Ivc5ssrWWy2ck2dqeJ@f3UrvZdYNJvUwtbEhY@2piQ0bAmiNkd02kNzBbwC9eBKGa9bvV8waigJJ4PrGi6vyFHTXSeuteWlp9Mp02dSCAejdNAJs9rT3SFJnIXIbZrIJOh6MfHAqxh94EtQU8@lToEuJpKXH6DQSYy8Eaek4VAAgAis4ZWfeADVwMCvm7b9TbQLObO4XyRd0LTyYNTNHXg7FozTBozYxQfZyQ9FTphNuaC0LBG78KBzhVBFSccqPKjDoshm153BmA3zCJ0BBFXPWXqQHv3wOy6jjsDKCAyBItBJn14PYAkdoZCMXRcgdhFjTWUlMMqgjoDrgEtH@iv7fs9Lwf9hO23BzUdKCV13h8d@ccOEkvK749s3@XmWsetAVv2oH2mghRS9UHNHk4ViNzCOvzak65AAGt6rAA99zcDoDol3vSAYZL7PgaOeMnEuAkEf8sQkALpgCil6RErPgSmcjZy6oo8QZRyksnYdmUVDBgxRM1nKLxNZvNrcJrOJQaLZkZPYaiU16@TQYvIpAgeg1O2pEcTRXtgHqVHsgyvptnxLPg6g04HrQOHczmFywoqu5EePQLWplBydrfXseu2X@W@7PFjIVOwJRjjodjURJlJhTiPxGBaB4YCYUT3w0PrvntGwq6iQkEe3U4kbPX7bp@n67f77jUjBwwmRZG673aRu7NXJHChBA3DWtvB4b3oS6krNWeKEGGfSvJyPK5/7dqOchNfWlqK5@JF6DGXlnbAtI2mHTQlwLRDJo1MGE5HE8VIkgl9yxQD3Srx23IAeahWsDkMsbd/a/cUs5zLrVaSZtkQ3wx@VcAz9BgQWsMPwImrhQIaVVUuXkNB9VpzsvT72Oud1ft2TyDhM/PK5HaBhVVCA1Sc28eBQR6Fl8U46Rb6IF3AYKDeVvrxi3L6onJxc9FIXNzGkxhbzZuFGhQK0lO6eqvvDkAMUctrOc2oqGp5FYSPWiGejq8oyqYGwzgYiaifbKoJk2NbiVvQGyoXF3FAqsBPud7uE7xhMqOqIaogHyjwgKytxPWbTUi/plbURBziqvEkDN0K8Thgpo5I8KjQ2JYmEHR8@jlHzH4iIVHzhlEp/u50p@CGg97J6CeDt2@Rd3EYtZDCOgOTS3k9ESB15ARhdfScGrQGXrUmQz46kcanbpOPivbxVXp2KFlDqq1Pjw9LpwVKpm16lyBTaC0MmwJZGbDSb@jADTqDhiXNCgNsA0z1cU5w7gATb9XrTHMZBdPqPBOR7qLO5kADXkOCp8u0TneyCF4b8rs/UQYCQu4Uc5H8Ug@yxIPPzFOY5CFw7P2zZxNTZN1LkCdY3eug8K31eQHAmlrhjg36hGOMHDuiMZoDAibQFsiXjXAuwHEdDXlhMJxzownxCREIQW4obaEkYU@EQcBNewhD4hjOpwjRHyVWlP73XQcGp5b@irihzICR42yVpc@U/0@4IKXXvXHrBEkfjL2OWQd@PwnuQmYXABA4UCo120fN3wE8PTigcfx9ZQRRqm46iL@GTePUge21Eb0wlsBeoN8ErOIgFSd3CGtHrA5SbgswbQ1tn49aoYWfYZSnpqeoOE7a5eMMpDKUkTFTwcwdCbBuHUb4FsjK6MunS1jJubL7roNI1ksAGlhRHutgCvgs9AIZ7e4eZQ7m43cWcMDYHWcjgtso1Gnk1j1oXY7bcVsuW4EASJq6zgn7yMEZThjl@GYPWpT9lhC023JhqD9Jg5YVzpmur4bjTRNDpii8/jX0Amx2occB5pT57Oi7JRBDjGw6DfkPbGl6wkJGoEyXER3rbBxArAJ0kG6wJr9r9dqj/gQ5ea6YN/Fp8pAaJp/JMkGEhFyJFv6WokYbOXeBdh54NQLTrLKXaEyAk3fRcfVE6SekFd5soISxKWd0DVAxAfROhY/rFxnXRWqCb4VTBVqz6/pm6gsdWDS@JJSQNZvJXiq@FE9pGr5l8mKZIks1rKsUcqkx5GHJqs@EPbSsegp9sXNjgWEmegLPOai5gMehFxSTfwMchDGny99KJJCxU@7CtHmmoZM/bw8syaq3XSZfwBAjWjIZOog2jJU1wDwIgDguCaOJFSHJdwcwrGtYHbtr@0c0Z99xcOyiE/PWkWsJ333gN2MAJ7YFAjmfcBh3MjivPu6jnBYPfwqcnKDCEF/nKO1bjdTKGNpz1@3DuNJjBs0pZELUd4VHyvV6Dd0fAgAeq0T9uxf08y@OD0rVk93zp4XUwOunOnYNeETDqnZhMNuB5jDnwbzhDGEJaMd23K4NJQpAvr3snLquz4UHXDh42BPDiAGMZwfVZ0d7p7unX4nMUY9udwcdE/OYW54KEMI4ozALwdTdmguyhTOYCwmEi@O942cBlM9ePjvarR6UTo7PI2C@HnRs0ximepeteQX6DIMwQ09z1B93GpMrOjRMnZhFEMwGx1x5BmNTpmnw1tCNJ4qjMh09UETG7lHTcBbYxHnuPssY6a2tRs3c3LTWG/W1tY2m2Ww01jLGZra5mc1k0/DaWN@y2DsKrmnWkGZuwMRnRXACCdOAzNPH0NcCCQeGonWQWEYz8xX6LshcPZu1Nta2zK361taWmdlorJqZzQ3LWt9orqXT1rqRbtY2jc3VhZmLZANFq7GtSzNA0OpwsoA8gfkp8JloDjzzIOtds0Ymk1mvZ5tbq5lGNr3WqG2ls5uNmrFh1rasdHNt1cgYjXrGyAVxcUYVuEQbKgylSgdE08BLM8BTlYLONFrFtMoYLEMLhrO8iiymFywj48BBeKyhx0AsIuPUrHDPonuwhIxTNMJ9Hd27uIA8lmTJGjqKgJsUENeR9X4tcNxCx3AFeWJtFVil4J@z/OdHEpBvjPQtAr/GNehI@W4Mg9yv/GZzwjlDzpcadmWdsfMqOfMV6Mm1X1HYO14zA4fw1ggeX7meCe@O18zAIbwsh4cr3rPBTfnMChoCWydguEI@E9aUx4yAIaQNghRdVR/7bZLfvCV1kdZM77mRQthbBJuvlle/5qsVVbFYjtTMG8g5SGLPXJCfn9k4b9@caDFSOAK/kORgGmFyImnskxkvkzDtavb6jhwFxJmB7Vy6NHAOTdW0bmQRSgiie9m5G7MJQw16TQS9k6m7Prz/6taa9JoRADvd6Zk58qBpT9H1Q1drpk7pgxOgs3IwOZU7kXzNag5gFJSq2Q6a7wmmbW1SyGatZs8LCpjAzQfBd0awHDsdwEg0o6/pRjDsxaUT4Nl8Hvb86JgC1kwaxE3O/7MJ5PuDvg@xxPe/fq8BlXC3itrmiMaCoaHqWNdEH825NSaiooVes2t33OsTYsh0H8i6iUuuZic0zAZNta9pbbPfxSGXqG4gUHwBJSygNZ5zPhcTfGcnkmOE5Ml1BubYXVafEZrCTi2J8MRokN1xzQahgQ@FbYsi9bGyeTVYQz4ojAg80PPMS2jGygUbbxXw2wN/wN@4O@C@arR7@FvUREXIdNasGRaIyGbNthZUet@8HDRcDSQ9KjJmbH1G2HHpabJOa3bMS26sonF28XkB@3arBfKE@M4Ldt2GsQ0NSlPX9LmPLjxn4PW0GlSWDw2HbNQUugtS6Hf4e14QW@yfCw3zsWZ36PWASg@Ji8gFRDpCNG5p0iJIs6fQ3DFrIxyqtz@eyjBBEnCA5xTqiUR6Fbu9cO03uhVpfnzsKyn@1tbs2HwzFUfJrOFVim@i0vgEMpVZbKu6p2Kh47K7ZkfLNCLGuRw9mDoem2YEpXkbrd4xPSAtX1SHdQXVR69F5I49Ux2GXf2xaQGxj7MTbAGYt5os2JZo1XW3Y3vYtDvzOOj0Atw4TdzORq/IlLQ9C7ENkpm8thaaZvMFt@7jUu4cQnsAl@OrqLhOHaEc3Z2HtLp7jb@5okXbvbL4e3ZH93Zmrh7AsbQOkYRdn9mjNOr3USpuB6LXbDxezsyXX@/MdJ9sA8EUR3SA9kC69uyO67Ezei9CS6sP0fh7NkVHMWibjkbrQVHz7GgiUz2mi1nWOfVqdlpuZ32zlTLhNbfyB/0m9gni@1DuF3Ivw7ifewXykesY4juX7V@m@pf31R0tTfRx0T5iXNADz2JhYlFyfgFhJIE7cWYX7jC9STH1FB8vz6uAfr19bY6C76/Qs8zDbtCz9EYkb4P4hxG2NsHg97kM/quktrY4tcbD2NMdsBv3FSJSuZcdCzoyet@pUpZJGx8Zw0inH86smp2BNbBm8qrj2tcW7m9fMAp5eKbSohjLYrYTZ4RwrjMM9VaMHx@Ua@zD0baQwZgdGxr5vZLOTH7XAxm9h0PuEzCcoOFuxJYz6E1U7sQozjldjLl2L2jZbmMik@jzsRxp8355akKQ9yz6LRxc8cEgrm0V1tLptJBvIvPXE5ZFg67VMO7XNn9PJEwu45THYXE2pB8xzk5jPJUKVW9fehpOaj6MO2XmzQhQ4K2tlGM7lj/C97wqmcVta67b@ZgqBKbbsFF@A6kUF37uq8o7spHYDcbGcx8ezpzUmvNmPXiHJEangD0ceC@ihujU64OqWcMla2ilrSnr4nmgyETufalAN0@TS3zrRGe@4ClmVAx9U99Y2CK5OOvWrI7JP8P1tUXwtvTVhfBCkUXIybS2hethfAVsvKIam@JbvREgy27AIKdtdS2yLhgdmI2vB17wmRto6OJvhrdO643z4vVsYBQOvidW2yKilO86MCzzzX7LwnFNB1fFhes85hzMqs9E7lHXbFn8XNUi7jme6sCtw3w0ODbOnvTI8V1ndYjGt34sJgVoTJfWyAu@MwE@H9WhPgfd@6fqptp9nTYq3dfQ9dTMxYR7ZEWn7badttXmO4FC27zmARTp8xNxiwoB@W@164z4U3SXUhSzHbfTeQhmkT9ybum6zZl5KuE5rQZE/Si4I7MGHuJz7xQg9PWEIOr057WbtjWALstzfbdnaWSbF7SDk0X8PY@LBos7v@os1MIZAsBI8P1V4d87Nm2Zrt/r0afa6ww8elFUjY7XzarKQ0rmIVRh@3zbEadbq@XW6m37vizVLNN37MtUMCPErQtHtr0IFmymHaCz3rEBef2RjtRQiPqf4edoXpWKySXebYWG2XWcY/uDfn@EmPBdl3kd93rMHyb3T4TTuHz1AQ3zciBWBmd4kzSAO@uCHWQLlkDEQuJcAiMhHAVuzUqDwGLMnVGa2N4ZaR2rq/w1Ty6aKj9lKrJ@@zFTomLbA00O2pGZW3CfoJ@JxeiZnZXTHrS8u@yOT9g3QMTC18ya3m3hmeapiuaVCj2Q6YjPPHxnOincvg3fKtTcwFq4upJduLxC4YyOZro2fKrwgToczJ0269g9j7@Z1szMFBjuLiHfDTWaPWwW9dOwmnwtBE33SXpdt4@HiECk0Op9y6vjVDpyZC4/ce7juC3gzFqHjQMHYWcW4e6q9czqD3s87csXVsvE7ZXPbNxp2ZlBFQB1evH6PqDfGZie/Z2B61sz4U0vYN8H7rnZsutPJzAfAAswKvbg8c8E2aPTXeRft22Pzm8EhgVzTkhknGyRzqog788arU1N14cHoxdPq0QEJbH3m2lHLNgjHhpwwQD9zZlpzZqJd3s0bhyRadEkvO3TzKz4zqSq2ZsAFiV/Pej2Bp74zE6d9ulEp6i7l@TuXdvAFrVvgBuzttnxZ09jR2ZmQeYSneTYOE8K/67dcVvsu5tpBiIadNoolM8guD3ork9MH1qEM4OAKe0HLpTipIfW5wX7BmjCWmWa7dj@4gke3zdhjBR8sTC8s8FTiKln@NaffCwE7Xw2Rp4tlGCgbx/VO3go/mNHApztAhWe0aF1NIbn5qN0L5Kx9gXAoHdxrOvoeG3hok8Ou1TXGfga7vJf1KesL@xTcmy4uR4hDaZ8p/T8pRqlENr@ep8casFAcOB1RmPT3I0HU4RnOyCszefFk6GD0cSBRSoNTmmj5j1xdnt4eopY/oE7a8RzMoLe58FDJuhABt0Dq44rj/em/cJ9DqIbdGU9YLrdUwu3DEzxktkRMdozt252AD@Ne5M5I7Az@orx4NrsWTWo387YNFsWmwX4wPTNObITTRzSCDA03Usrdqdm9b@mGcGIed6gdjJDT60hDUPmEwxvhZpfr3OBG6flJtrI9NqO13Ndh7@JCafhYzxfzGyge6DXw1fcddy/PNH7zRykTZb2@IpvN7Ea/ODevOL2rZrb4W8swhx24Nh8c4HZty0v9cx2BkNyYxrIbrOHOXwbb1rfwGkOrw2N7dqGMXa4uxc3q/Gtwt7USApE4ivToyX/2WOaiZ3ED99V1Db7dRfXzoThI1fOIkfC7uHj4VZpvjWhBpUyBIZm1geBXoF7strp1rr0mjsmidT0qVXDI3c1Oj/qm8NZQuTk0THhOHV4K2Bp2PDXmXICox71/o5sesg2iXG7Ry9i6NczySRI7oVt1d@a6j28NGxFNJecMmlEO7MhTW6CAzGnY2l@G/dYpnx/HsN4YV8OGg9Y6woWUAZdC9esJ1du5hKV67WJItzZq/Qhw@1bYus27hKEph@Yketqu3NJFsHD//HeZynomKvra3iCfzDUWsDO7t8XAJkf9B3xeQjZnbie37SHxz1U4@T25/EXLFYWosCHNwc0rcwrBNSnM@jw@Y5WZEdXt0HjO5AGmy6YOsTCfUuznCuNVBwNg@XKvhnokZlbh9ObQ417dodee@F6IHhoPY@@qZ53cvTs@FzvecaCmUPc8DewO7i6R1kJ3KCAZJo/RX1Ge9UWy5sHx3ulZ7tMaQCTcR31ntBiQbTXNmuWb6bMueMc9LX82ULf0/PnzxLjQ8tM2W/33a6lRr33z86SkBH22dlM72jsQ6DupjucG/2oZBjqDPJ76dBy4DyWNyOlEJI4JkQajULdF15SHGADN7svDsl7eqCeS5z2I@YdnDsBR7NeH@A8EzQAnVFARTETCVWVRKyn7jXrou4fjOTRodVLu5dn6cCI9dWG/pnC47F9hS2bbLvAMuk0U9U814ABlQsUOrDyrGkHoHc9z245kIUgB6S8CBWbcL1IHoNBgB/ALZfZ8s0wl84Zt6zA5JzMKhWeY3wokdKwR5qHTnn08rJZKSzHNS2@HL9wciwdD4NbHRj8zgxuToSFzOJHZDjEL9dK5pJKsRCbea64BTolVIrUNp1Gx2KilqH8fa5@hOu2OcfNzH/xBw2hK4p0onVtz@wAQlDdGxBc273e4ekG6Or1TNQ1hTCu2zhRjalr@7sMBtF@vc1VREF1vTw83xSKZ4RuObCc8KnIMBeccnA9FA/R@pwweG7CA5Ei4TBWUCgYnQ26DohDDb/t6ezMpvOxg/74xIvQuOf4fVz0aCTZEWtYuG@Ujj3TGl/HdS/pKBTm5C/@gKvbocPP4lBqkDyp2YqkiGecDdJxU6@7A8h1AOSt1XdFEAWRbNb9Aa6ok5Y3clfxSDDpAQJq1wItOJQMV4Wzv3vGtBKLo/441FqRt5vK8u7pp1@U05XCe9ZNWf/1eyn1RiBO/kTbWvfkJAuC5G@RsKLeWfAe@8aZvDyUeYLhyXBbjL@ueX2g7jtOZHg4PKAx1@0FzQYFelLcFVKjUIihoJnqOVCH0yUlaESw1jWpw6EjiA72MKSEz4MGBlaVQPNWV1hWBnyRVzvzWRYSRJVCJpi42jQ6K42qXTDK8pC9Y9QLgERvZNNg44jsoDahbmEvOFWwGj3tkTqwagPa8XyV0TPZAhVnuVrYLpIJJAYXtXqVX18MM2ntYrhRqsAYRSD14mL4STrzJWDd7UOsxylseaUXBzfLejH97p1njpgs38bz/HQKsInlm5Ojk9LZ@e75yzOohduAtR3yM2oBr0EqomOnbbdD@tIALzhY@Aj@E9rGbBA1cqqqFD0gSEEFrmVNXubGCGuaiH1P9FnxPSvifzeA4GlNm0lhzwBUYBKxIdaw8IMean1jIq7QXEVUZmP/gQ0oRAyeAZrBSwlVMisAsjRA1gNRxeYXdoe7PQRj90JZjLadmUEQY2F65dCfF3EmCm7/XsrdMz3v715uDmVxuSnMgnJD0NA1iHO4e/Ts5WlpMlrQyRPXLWxlxclYzpyxpfEBR6CqixRSiIi4SF6QmUwRuFV0ZlxhqOVfW1AswRzrXR6ZKJTyL0tjwgTMFFBnbUVIIYpCOUD5BgWR6YO7MBqIZDHooyPgbngRQyZwKIegg4zrsoAcI92rOj5BMRCqQFfQ9E6IiQt@Hfei4k8yaHFYNOyjBx5vc3O6qrDX8Rj8R3qlwJSpsCET3ZlRYRrLwK9jOS0ocBBWzfM@ii1zRMjLPO9ymF/UmQl5anxt0roUHUgRB16hl@6YPS8QBmPshetbOfbNwCWlGgEzCeULUtdqchW3VLVccSsp6wCpGAYBQb9F8I4OzwoonXHRjPh7lOYGDnZUEIhrmxXH3v0@amXm55G52keOcldoGAy6Sprb8YRGsVBK8NiV7dm1DqevJso4HeCUWBpRcNRYTOpU2G7HA5mkAd03SCg@drUgnOh0SpIfldQcJseAJvVQZEwyWcKwXuGuxjnoSq9xsPCGR16mcATZi8CMby9pGmCuZTuBeuIc6iumaY0c8/sD3ARZjN@JEmQhRyat7Xc7kYAzdG9eWKkPv/nbXN/mhQ/mHwnzML0Htl8XtiaYfyPwMQyw/bPQlgHbj7ntdQqr7K6SwXE@Q30Rc8@VAnE@ke8UDBlDoKiZChRWOVb3F0cnzKuj/l@s0C6MvMZ1hWwmGKcwuwuUcUUVjcF5CuN6HMNRyl8AnQBxAZGgjINiDaVn9SsK6pvLpVKYcVyu0mk3qjXkO0RI/dw3A1S7CpJYaj27vmakIJPaVQCQNOK08HAcB6iqOWCM0pXdK7yp1dn29jaTvbrZsQrreU4gqWXz9ar8JszoMoSV@GihzCAORBnHAL@iiKYsmwlDxajYm8WNODK2hsvpDURChQwQREVnJ9ChATKnK1AFxOxYQ5/EplEwCgKu7bgRfcsBIA0AcdioHHS6TY4PvOEca6SV6tFqkF9hMJpkyMmzKLb8ml34F05FKIllQH0/n0G/Dpj/yQzNsZyyUEfQXZWlyrTCUSwNe3LmuDhVfQi5ZUomlVlNGetqhEJlAQryi@39HYCEFg4co27ZX7s9b3e/dPTZ8cnZHdVVFDI@HSzO4sXtxIWmJ8uV0BAP8z2J1L3D1NnzvcMAldFcjSeLMcR49@90NmelNp3TOam/4mcL76ZNHncSMtIPBUwzTdoh7aK/C33sm4oE3OdHm@6kqqg3t@XKdvHCid1J/t0sdcQxfQWJC0wXHikjjk9nE7MYXj1wjlcPeHpwcN7AU/N4nNJ3L8dn8IVDxIMHD6AAB5D0VBBqHvOEDBzzGaCxspgMv/vAI9bHZ4lISWyYo0jI8@CWBGxaY92GQqlf2/TaHbsmQQfeQEWXXCVPoHMmVOaje72O7SuqRFMgBRSDgIkp4q6EYW6o0xq3QiqJCVaSLdITGMBTJWgEAC9@MvDa7MTtRea2DqzAdArSCDsY8AVQi3026EK4Jn1OLWSxFsgnGkQGRMXDrPJRNbQsoSZwmEBVjJBeGZUFioLr3UZWGap62xo27BYwcEVNQkv/xACxKlRkgIUm1YFOHHgcx/CneKQsitKP0hY5HAM3y6ZuOw1rqKD6o1wF5FN0j1@/uoqr8h0aIJWV@4GSuyndlUFDNH3RIsZ6H6ca21Z4QcKUctGtLVQhhToZoFogxTO//wyM0D8pza7ZY8qAlKp6TGdkVS4UJ@n5fZVpRa6XxWGJBI2q4UMeIDVj0CaZiHCYgvOQSqoAtYOuntPAz1u7x8qGrlfATImobBln1PahK8e5KFWCURJEyRHYAtYty2GOOPXqnPIgDvpLpOWNoWbRGd6kC5TmcF3EBZWaFR9HtGONWyDH6tZWTtTGJKvZYkAWd7m8ngKwM1hIIKUCfsURe8Aa6srHSxVwhQXYwpPPLcexAEFAM10T@mBzAETWV5PB5SjJsW51SiHGs/hUnNmHjE7qXC/Fbzq4DL@cytPkTP4W@tQ3F9ipNkW3Okr9jyk9lb9RljuFUQoEHbWoLLcLRmJ1JZFYdlaUZQe7@sePcU7ndhkkiaoOQ6QhBNKWO2oe6Bkkj8Kyk182t5XlRiGzQjHACoO0G4jw3kvpN8vmbWr5MfTUSXDp88arLHuktjOt68Yt5A9byHIqCTRzg1oO6WYUTH7ZTiQwD/pyFTPwPnVxliCefXGWoumjvJBGU62uaG5TXDWsiTv3wnAECmdR0cDYM8jYxVGJahB4rHF9dZbfHNmDJ/w5nkZjtAHW8qLivzzp83DGIvhdnDSqcSWpXG8qIHCoABLRmjRVFZjJL38ZM9aZrCzvrK92rhLxbDoPLyO/wbLsk@WLzFqMxZ6Ypg9D9tTKzcXBZuuKWc3M@jeaVrab@jeVk8uTky@HI/VCicf2j1/LxhoE3WBb9Hvos8Eycx72cU8stpKSYqkV4/FGKvXmzRsQefEpF/ViEESvqGUtXikrG8KhW9zYWEmub64kT5/Eq5AXKK6qZDLqGbPtFLuwe16jAT@3TfcUKTH@sJ0dTA8M8M@EW3fYJONw12q1BiVzxN3t2AA/h76I@/y7r169QsMretjbUxE/xiEKcLFc1czGKJOZdOYv/mTpNnlzUt3@i@93U9YSfo7x86Pb52g@M7KfLC19sre3tpYExHHzyXdPvtrd3V07SGZPytmdNS29tP3nf7a0lMlsZ1JLFc8zKvHy5ZdyJr0m63/xe/Hqycl3PA/rDp9VZoAR35vwM1g2yy7ZW3gumwz/yfy2ETGbaK4132IHCcJygZhNPJ5djZ@9jmP9vI0ZhhEb0V@VirbEjOLOxn/7yfE3MT9WzKRe9eHrx76JrW/GuBEMYFsNbFexYmwbg63fxkapQqEAxo3/9u8hfvEzgIM@o214FbMBrPVRrKgVKMq7WHEdDEYmA@n@P9/7nhQrDiETxeLRIcsUMyuCTIzNx8ZjMjl@GwSMi5ixuXb8hKy29eQ4k81so9mx8H6XNgxHkckYRuaCicozRBVicQ18cwfWBjPWqRtjQdBxnbOAopigBCAQohFuFg5ENtwBvSfCvbowzZWNxFrmiZN/FXkmLP8QzylepLW@9OTNQSq1XYSeHp9c7slFVTSzFNvYlF33CU7@5dkz4ZrH19DVNBeCw@@CHDV8BAJjm4VklSMpaGWBDxvbWNQpJnDJwgb1K4Qr4fOX/9df/vQvf0J/P6Xff5ZiwTYZrXxVKQYPUJBc7Ms3F8LqPGfP@eM48A@/wIou6AAmR8xNxsKnWMQX/Qsbmeg75SZ8iqGFQoyjzA3HAo5F6Uqx96kUy2EtXRWL0fLAkwqtVAyeczI8j5RuXD5RHmCNOztL8Ef/8IRWfC@Ri3CmIHefJVZc8CzuA6RYOVauVHizni7RgudUR6rTha0a7VWupJgGjCqROAUqZYK44blI3PO8hJ@uV4UtpY@hxqTY3/tTlFjsBp5KQru9LcfX3Pi6@0R/ncjnxT/IefnQhg83QQ4rt5q2/bqYSJQpp@WiyPK2xipFXgB669XX2wA@sV3eLrj79NOriC@t8rpY3p6MTPErxSdPEojaJwCguFxhMLSA2rjdvi3elrdvb7e34X@b3rfiC66323f@6TN@5oQZ@1ew/i/KqeJFSrTKYgXsOhA1uOipC6Ru@EK4clmK3SDlsHKFtM8VtLKxnq1ojFrICnCvVM5YyaymssNP1ksZYAIeBs/IcmoFDe@wuwSBZ0uK4dBhi48gtsjhzYdv/w/8XXz49t@CFbKG1/yRb@0b/Hv2Fv@@8fHvvI5/p9/g3/lb/Dv18e/Ew7/nNfyTYgXGQGJb3kl30ldp49K4BIPN0iAwt9NtowGdDUtbLD1Kj1i66xoNMFnwlwaTnW6ydIulnbRjGOAJBp@lfTQ14dOCvyZA6cOfnU4j8PQVg1Q62IWR1mb6vqsy9UIqs/gbC8Qs3dDT@rpdrWTXe9@U45V8LHVxkeKyJ8us5UlL9@0tY9Vq6cVBtZpC4r947h6P/4@Pu1Hrwv/usfv82O268H98fPz8AhhYMfEkoT2Bp1BMbIvPTqyY37nIaUi4AQnHUts7F8VVDc3rCaDKDLolPvIZQ4RvcelCgrH5q1fXeepn89dX@es8GUIrN1RFABGMGyBWXvTP4ALxLl6lqEe9hueK4JINjdfgGZi4IfXq@gIlSBgvhP@Ajqj17@Hf/v/X//OXTClXVGgEN7fbCj0q/qnqze3NrXgXVUURFmUb/tAB7Bjl5raIRgp0A6ayolbU21vuBm9F3eYAi5jGdpEijwMCp4iFaVK6/KX8/X4xbf5cxEFMgpG0IpYBLy6G6bSar4FLuBZgvqMVJTVPe22Wa7gKCKNHQ6UQ2bV83ljh5sxaJp9fE5aNzXx@U5iXFWXr7lNM7xjr67nM2pqq5vNpERbGifnACCAsz6znsZHnYypmlrd8JY2zkXQ/R1zOyY8fK@JGl51eT3382NhKv3sXOlWrDbtfraL76rt3clXGbTmFrSzY05vv3gHTiatuX3nh8gVhRTPYJ5kipbDl9qFUG@DNjFRmnGbb9Ezf7ytv7V5Sxl2ZnqySTu102u1fxH/x4@9//yJewI0a5LpmIABMhWW3t9fXisX1NTCvb0LB5WW@80dpJbYM9XY5JfPiMnk5HhNexuaGSq63cfRnsW22U4SG6uHDbm5jVH9sLasqtZGl3oBL4GZsbXFHtraubCa2xF9hSWXFFSb@yuXyamJtZWPlSQXEm7sPMtX8jVmIp1Lx28KNmcNZq9t8XdzdgOelzMePV7cAmZvp/IVUrR7snu9W8dpHXJOH3o@hI3FoCddbe/14maYYs1uVMhaschGP5/JPqNqNzSyLxfMinBYHbs82t6j8Mc@T7CYenBwS1KnfSqzHjI1V6FahV5V6tD1qI80auMLcZ26zuQSOUHeshpsBPKvTCe67uHb7nca13bCWpNjJs9390nkyAxJKLHO4u5/MnL3cixlozY7t6M1iq@hwWto9OH4JMU6elXbPSp8efVF6eQLunvT1W9OyTGtgWdfVweD6G7wTwapaPXAdP1Wrbnvm11@bPXpglMKZ8/WHn//ww8//pw@/@@MPv/vDD7/70198@9Mfwu8P4Pdj/v3xv9vK4vsX3/6z3//wO78Ljv8Zfv8Jfn/yi29/63v8R/Y/hd9/ibj9qfhFwvGfBLB@/Rff/uT3fvHtb/wMfv9S/H529/ebfzL799MfzP9hvJ/8/uIwP/738PtDDisI@@Pf4W74vRP@d3i43/jZh3/xH/j/n4s/NP7uh3/xp/gSln/6sz//Lx@@/x8zmc0//zcffvjjDz/4yYcffP/DD3704Qf/OPPht/6NkY6@fv/DT//ov//xH/73P/5f6P8P6P2HD/n/8LN/@lf/51/933/1x@L3J/D7D2D6k7/6j0Cqf/NHP8f/n/zR3/ynn@P///6v/uaP/te/@fV/TYbf5ob/91/@O/7@6@//8K9/8M//@vvfznn/cOH72we4f/sP4PLwfD4EzkPK9bEu3/5K@fm7YGOcCtAAXT7BMiDE7o0smq74ZJiTPmGx4go@wJPLm5nNxArInytbW8CYK@S@jUGYBO30p//kw2/9GpD/vwBgYPufwQb/3AJePyIL@/LLCU@WoCkQLfHll@gpxoxfRkP9CBzepUAaTz95ByG@JG/@sDAYpPu/UTAIx0SwINxkBigM7vHk7r/49p//HnmEcdH51yZApgPnaOhlDP4uKOqPsN2PSxMN/SNkHR9@/r0Pv/ePP/z8tz/8/Nexb9DWtpK7SejaF8/yQsDsA8JhwPWHhIOABo4ZYYy/JGXAsLSNM5OSkXjzBnK/BCYYcq1I2VWwSUaRzAaaIWICbARkOEzgG/6ltS2GFnAZkit8WQK89hJ4KXlCGhbAj4LibeYMjcVNcBri3EIB4GIkHidZ3YTBDBvuERSIWUicsupKYcgjJtChSBCQbCR0OpWNjJzYLBxAgoXhAUNYCDwhvYHvm0JxszAsIrj3lAWAkdiDJCEUXpaeGBbfg71AMCG8NDx4D1nZLCQSxU1wKWAhE5RaskppGlkqHJU9wajc6M4Y7rXceQJNRjY2ZT73AahkIjS@E@PQGBCCg/9FYkUUh/4DI/1WMD7U05Dww924/w46U3wRAOBqGm7Rg5@mYW6egPeQg0pQsvBJcAiAuQRJUQFIcCCBJSElqH4TZIH0IQ8f92wjq0BwWJzl5WUwbRflVbl6DGNIGKz1L3Oeb/ZxCZEEyRyT17dkdMb9Tnwn5/IJDTZXDlbgbcB/aYl2L1NZ8ivSchynLeI8a5CWllh119wYL0ZQRrKtUBESFJB9Aj74e/IEzIAj@o7dcKaB/hPS65jEYlT30FiS/A0fvUDukaZEDq8LUmJsp@lsHkPXk3oyKb46fclBFwadfMVXXyaJkfFxDy1UM2N9jamSQtd@qVhDdYukMem519pzhzDmSMpy0ljHxSdVzNOc5zLYWqVSLg3vr9xcrvDeWNuQ4Ev2AV4/Ji7CArrBS9j17W2s/@KNRpNJaASZdV0qFsW6OzOk4lnpHIKfHzMjk9YZjFdu1jYya9m1bGZ1fT27kTHW1rfW1rObq8BZ19PZTMbYWlvb2tzauA2x9QSYUzK3UstuF//Rned/@Eezntmu@EjFL9lQpwn0W6nYKfD9n8u4Bi9fpOU8zWwRLpfL6ST@ZVZX4Q35TBrZjcrSUudGw2Jf0KbDG9zlAFmVbjTs@B7Bw6RHEnsETvBAGrgKycS@kaPjvNgjgLeI8n0CspEFQoZ6uABK5uCgRm9ubiI/Kbb03e/6rFiEcYd2dCjFoA22WbAqrtkNva3T5Z@NQd8i3xZjB0dfHJ0dHb/QD47OYCDwFcuspnUpdnt72wzXcshqsePjYwmZHwzwVg2Mf1tng8GAfGtgvx2aUi/65PElZTJaZlVbNTRjFf/vMWTw/@HhM/CfwTfEWs1I/MRgB4/uBFNmW9I2139RDG5112tuY6TbeEkNnh4r@KOeRRdt0Gm6c65mfqkQD69Nje9kslu5MHpgeA61sJNZz0Cb2NgWSqmK254/6lhFTOKmYXu9jjnKOTDSvsW9ozmzCfm7qfM9Fzk5k92Ub590rYZtMoiPgzQcPytdvOkBdxbn0hdp9WZm1PW0fHsLyVJy0rbQalGkpfAyNI8KXoBXrmwH@i6K0vv374e0@yR35PhiG0pmbRPdmYQ84TF0to8Nbsyuj41pNJ6jbpIXQJ/QqB32DHeT@y47d/mu5T2rPifEftuk@wD3@y4MZn/1MHumc8m9DmyuJCH0emqilmSva/vtOSFe9rp4WNLq/4NBKHVrkEEkCx5gD179juvOCrDBXp7MKeXzUKcR7lghpUYQ/PTo06fnke95aXf/qbTO9o5fHEx9siJQlj0rHZ6H1g3uG0TNhiC@Kj17Nm0VH@gx8jR7scSyG4HBYDHTNwtysiqX2Vol79/uGNuPHxvLqZNnOD9y0gc8dtwUYxfvte0vtOJmvm8NfWfAXm4B/y6WoKoByH6/sLfchD4ImloZGMrh7n4Fiq3jJEnH0qvFRpeab8Zs1oDkc5kcW2esc8OWpee4T3bL4Ie@bE@is5d44RxeLulLqEShgZfK4/RWDW93H/TYXEf4oBMaod23oV@8doMAUs00Gfw@9oH40ekOwNtCB5@nQW53fDozguPGDLvJ0pLOUbS1md3cWs1sJje3Nteyxno2mzQySWNjc2MLeqS0sWmsb2a3jOTm2tbqGnSb4Jvd2pBi0JPYzVQKZBNDluGbA7BOHe9I2cbLZly9XZRinAWyt4qpQs2H9gGTLYgj4219nk9HAVbsgpxZw3M6qwYDiCars9jh4X768FCW99CCax77aVluoCW7mU5v7MmyRT770LVnZNnlccALgvnckk7v7cvygANAjUuy3EZLaR0HTrJso2V/9/AQ0/kaLRmMD8EuuQ@3dALLBgRz0LK6SiMvWf4mBAfhdnlCa5TTElowTfQ55D774CfLnwb5SacBwikPxyE8Dcq6uyvLR9yyu4s@n1HBszyrn6Nllx5Z7oMFiFCWW2BoYU8gyzUwIinKch1M9ZEJbngfDWrhcXxTlkccQYgiWR5SaLN@KcP4QLhjMk@fPjXbfsNq8WfU5986ZA187OGgdFj79NNaq1Xrj3ZLn56iz2efPTW/Hg36tVZNRKtV4XEhDvhcdkfTD@TxqFo1OzN9PgcfZ8qnOqpamLeq@Q3kSTwtTKRb/Qx8PgOfGROzQw4Nni4EreGz14Xvnlkjn@AhH/oOazU5j4SKvTxOpGKbuXSAFyS7Zr3v5tE@LCyxuBJPjsrr6Uqe3FlXYepNOn@L/k2F7jxF2RpFTfVmVB4W0hUYOW5kxIkiRb4YZrK2nFzq7hhb2dySuWNk1hLDHCrVdptxFteMHcV4vPJWeaHuZFbXcvLFzo4ml43KTsbYzK1vvF4ZyLKaw/fO6kbuLQjgcZCy8aWWNyo7G9lIlI2NhJnK5DY21PwtIMSHzqg28K1qVVGuLfNSVTHD2MUr6g2Vlo2opHa@qQyTwwLPFRsxNT8sGHmuD4Klp4AxRWmgRqIB3i@oMgLaYgByuJPOIatWZGNrU4Y8pFKKqiJjQlYC3zevguW28BMxTBj5o7Ocxq8nNTbXVR0PqFTdZpWuaGNvoiFxFCG9wtNkdJI82PRJAz8vJ53joAP7AhKp7BreiEw6EmD4zfVoMT4TZWxsSVJRyNwn/HKovLB@@nRfBzFc2FC7kX44cBALOl7g7E/4cM07gdM59Hb6Uwu3ctYDt31@xlsvDWGMhedY8jfaK@02GuMMhhY8DTzmkifVDnhgHNU82Q1mFopgMhsKJQ9lU6@pnNVisVAtdK1uzx/BqJMv2EOpgugvBl22x3hYPH0WnL2pFvYAAem8g6oOLbQuD2NDqdhARU57hb2bQQ6lxNu8VbD6fbcvx/DE3o5TGDie2bROrD4eFjs6hj7cwlNZ9fabixIG3Adk39xqxT5zxoU48jiOwqM/lKEbzJDwqBbSt/lorhVTK9bUfKtQxqDv8LWtyXJF08rvKjCGzEtFaIL5UcwseIMavwszXYPh43p@CG7Gxlq@zWqF2uthvl/owYCH5TuAxchAjpm4sRayC2DevlM@/Nr31G0tW@BueQL1rgPdbVWvFoZjRK0WyhkY5YlR37oBI78MbhNMZtJbyYwBPS70xBAXfhtgX4MfhIEOOWPguFDpKDCOk5PpYVo3koZlJJX0G7vxhqlJ3y05UF3pXA5rDWqcrPA11URmpaM0XGZua0QAwALyVCgz2WY9O9lWINapZXZ4cFVTtG921hPZdOKtqua/gWz3l5WGvqfurOUbyh6rquAAIgT8Mmx9Ld8sKK/VSfyrMFBVltSCZ31D2EZmQvjoLUFlicGvN@iW02wJsHCjVbXbjun5y8ZGJlceLJc1A4qbftfalr9blCtQcbdMgr/oIhrIKHlwC5gGl2rGcsnYrYeCaMeCOja2MnkRROoJNqbICt6izrclK/H4RiYeV@N5nPNZAnfBBolfxYGBxh8bOzLIRXJO3sqA/5j53ckBH0Suw2j3VsLRHIPhZOxGur253Y7unfqcjUZmQgusjxlrJZYllqLdDXo1xpbIpOlFmpnbLey2TnfzIvTuvhTL0ba@8cYrdiGOcTMttfSxeyoS28XX/HuB@4cgWYkUf5VZRQyKM6tQ6EbEDgX0biSOVb6vJrWdKLLUhSTL1PT5uuxmVuV5Ze9jdIkG279pCp6Ve44DSqaYOd6kyxX1/Qu7c7O5qvFBqcJi71kipdPWsGrqfQy6jVvCdbAP8PM3mSxg33EDBxh@@sAcoZfJZmWcg7LesN7Z1uuN15uvn788fnl8yJ6kc5u5zalJ6IsnyaQRN@Lb7AnIuvZpCcYy75ibNd47n/HNkrF8LNeLr67FV6ejFmLDwlqw8K4YxaJmbGfYDtAqywH/ahrrWvpdkRNekTzWM@Dz4dd@tjbc3gR7BmTKHOA0m8gUi8ZKRo31Pnz7b/G4303pi91nLI7KF/72z34vs/G3f/avaJU3fptHt8zqRgxCotFY34jd3PRubm7h4X7ZWCXG87S2oYKZ70AwYsWUcDY2DDXmadwG2c3GvHdCG4uSSW@C3/4xt8nrgM3YVkyKbT5/846xbRhoFhutlp0hUyp1Z1Z/OQeDOfhn73EW77229KZQXE4BAeCU5BZGCGadVorF4gouF7B4MYFHVzNZWrUo3@YrjE8L4ShmxaE/y1vBP7S/5g4rngf2wBusOGO8bbFs0WAw8kmlPvzab2Uy63/7Z795ob6rvqt@B1jv1tbWupGJ/RLyseA8WTB0oYkPPBmGhnDIw@Zc4KfXZSlGM0GMhw8GQDjkwdPUXBcN2qQr7KkJxVXAownypkLBVvBUTJIkTzpCq@YlKZTPSLLst@pJgsFWUFsqtB3pRnqEXtBhsQLwJunRGBQ4dFGJTb3qdQb9HglJCsUzKkn2GKJACo9Q7cESneYRDE4z8iy1cjcqzzLXgEKdPetanoeaj4D/So8gyjOgUrp2hfVMPBGGIflV7hiE8kkejTKkXYG0OzxClVwVKj0PkGQ8dzySA6Kn9AiPt5BsCh0xs7chQJ6p0iNAAJRBEYDtCttmqyq7sROJ/FhR0i3u0cJT8mZw3kTCaAitgYesgsh5DGdzZQiDPioIYqKG61bUMQDCYfDFhAJIzRidbCis0JGyB4MCWHS0WKGiscePx7kqFOyGyqhECB/1RKFyp7FWmzsJALBgvPFJIycnmZNIYGU/miQ7wHiCsgtUp5FhHKiJB3/QeitJ8P9gokWKnKoq8shjAUR98VZRB5RBZEQ7r8M6aroyMhsqCzNfh7zXKVOkMCMcRF0MP9FJb02dZ/FW@mUsUDco4fXIEZFf0O30gSMGfGmAF9DgaWrODMRRIn41ATKnIz@IHcaCotgdCt20@yBj08JIoHpDWTVUjNYMXSgftDcrs8Zw21RWxQ/FwtCooMFEZQcinSWa2iUtUV7PdUg7Ap00xc1lpLPKk7guCJ7tgXNtkp4jngrtxYrkiCuPQson3UYOV@Dk8bi4CFPrwzgwwE2SWS2d1IBktpjCFZLhMXQnBKdSJMowDJlMxHGtY3UhS2eWxfCEvpdLpVq23x7U6Ej@cxvoqn1oQ7fheClx1U3q2r60U@eopVJzmyCriiNgMfaF2bFD7Tji3Dspt@rYeDc9VqsycYbPY5n1JIh7ScDs@AeIzeHEJJ7TS4N3koeC3wZ8NrhxMxmJu6SM1LvfVWNJqaokFpDikj5eZ3NlOhH80vNOEoM0b@QFB3TpxBjY9ZDlQsvkp3TieEwnPD4miZPEBTrlquOMcU8BcSo4V4ZGEDGtKwihGRL2McA068GBN2zFUNpH1AFQ24OWhRos/H4OT4IWULeTUoemJxi8wz5hqxm6JJyfjRZHmQEGVn1hEjr4QVQsh@c3oGJ0PvwGvgKts9sAvxgqdOHkh/ED6kYzaXMZkzdbEuCw06G0Cow3i8CSjViwdXDdXFD0JfBchxzOyMmSIicAbEJWZQ46jD8dnVO7RLwkx@5CSjKEIFANUFBU2DM9rjlRqJ@4vr7WSQPKoG/rlocqLT28pivVa9kgjbopH0bZ4jYCG6@SEddkjU0aV2mLt7rtDOkyta3HI/6VpCaeyfxmYPctJd704tgHXgGv7LW6dLwcD357RDeHNql4rSu0VucJMstUkjcBmeWQzLTN@C0CYQzBDJOjZD0JwJK1@mWyed3IC48rancAHCrLChxROVk/sHS9wGT3mmEI16dtnoG91rmsux0XRQ@ZzzKOk@YlDEKOAquw9@whRHKsa7bb75sjhfxVDI10qoxIumEj6N3JB4zQm7AbrsPHHpZHlYnowzA69F3B2IP18XC5dLMYKFedhP5D7j8E/yH3H44TDZItDytc8kKnWywOEjfqiglCIphREOaWa34a@xBkkIuZwUFgyNGE2y386gWKHeCb26AeCwFhAE2QwjUFNb2VLyqOZ12vVBKpFtC0TIiAGgfQ5Qrh9LoRmhH7natOz/UmnBxUpQKdj8g3OtXbgho4rWAZwwoiwuD4slHjRqur80kU3u@LAgMEFLfAEyWAXV@x1Xyo65I8gXDK8hjHPGNlkZkKCVnCS7iBVMRRzxEbBVSJAEL3sEiQTfBhQcsRCosFE3jVx7sdg7AaadQnpZ3xShwwOdVUOEvJUyVFcqVpQTYB7SiVFqaLEvhDVZSnvCLFvBX1H83@0kdnvwntYnbuiWB5v5CXok3FGqKCQks0F8IqKxYi9Qo5SK2YHasPHVSJi6GiU4ZkVlLBaIKng0XgijWVSOXXVV4/tINeduRcSAqjQgGKOCrwZsnbRYBSjvAwmieijQJCEPE5AwEY6ZnRLBFtGI02LBQ442DDOdGuI5kcUiaHPAoPPZyTyYqIBoOkUHUjVk8FNXaBQCUDPIP3lqidUmaeeYUqSNnXqGEDBk9BmmOeQ1QgaAglaaSzemVm6uVIpiNMawoAEuIdAA1@P0JOmmZ4hhbaQh7FURnwKG4TZMB5BRAYseA816KkhERGQ12Q6@UE9QPQduVEWZIN3CtDf2n@k5OBY/Az7jqmJ0Mak47p5NTfP4hjBTEbaaARIcNIryFDxgHLLimVALHk2mXKDOEZ3FPBBZipWsetpbombi7Am3LDazHVYDxAauOe9Fzf9N21tRwfBNlEXy9FcBbRTc7HAHbLcWGoEdXSZnOtck4clefV3ZZje1YSL@LkIrhFS@FclbQUlXuF0fUkScz68WEpguYEhKJrtYqXuFSrimd1mmouVIGIVh3pMB6XcDwLpkh84EMC6HFPcfEWYl@9HyaqMBTRzu36pXLcE55xSGSXAbOqgzwPvm0QVZjnjkeCpFsMReOar5Ai7bbbdVsg3qHeQIw9Bf5oDBszZPZ6lJckM3GImosoeqTmoNSTpiqifv7RUdnnGcVUw/iZSQATyEiy/jSOEbP9GclV5ybHowXpnX18fs@i@T1bnF8aVU/nmQ@1C9zz45JeVcYQIOA4G6v3ZyMp1PTeyc5EVkJnFKB4hAdnsUGbdxqY010IuiuC602gj2Ro80h5iMj4F/Pwv7gCg@ilh1afiXdanY2A33Rxj5hCquS9YPFHgeBHKvKeu8mFpH3wwLQgLMgR7BBlBZBXiXE5qJkGGmYPhtGeHC55CMD30Dzu0blD97Rxp8A9Z@Spf5Vkl5n5VXRQbVgdc2Q1FBEyGYEblPgURmbErx5WcGR0xPRcPqhToJNSo2ptEek8UG4OyZjJq4hS4ztheBA7pB6a@aYcHs3HH/rfYc04ZVfgs88g8MfjMdJ/TerKe6PeiGv06/ALFwQf5f0Pr0k8R3g/QgAPYnk/OU5WXcQ@T5WwSA/oEcKw@mSRSXdP0G253d7dOvw4FN1fUqjcSKRCUMsTOofn1bi9qMYjVBHQJF/PeRhJ3kd0D6a5CKlxYGMWtv9xXcgdyLh7oF5XohC5y8Iac507PAHdaN7NmdOrVGcw1DAmcTrfpnE1yReqhEPgI/jiBNIX8EWALcuvcoIKyoZzVOJqDkY@XbMXkVqEC0jjACWCxUCzPGUjEkoKzBD85jZMsz43zfqdNOsTaYYtYDLJSCCpPpGkqAWsnkVV0LGa/hzujF44SIbPIrYNj@OafZyWuInb8ZydZPGreA4YctyK50oKMOV4I547IIMXz52R4TKe@xwM47YVfxfPBc0CA/TBSoYn6C5YONrr8dy@ot5KPir/D9LV47mwTiHMDrcSRgAVWG6QGnHJzHFFMf2@BR0bCZVJhhTjJXGcRBMuSfql4Z9r@ea3UYAnzlmuUGCWYMZEpxHpMXg60G0E@h9ntOSc6M1Lx4e0@2asRh38EzCYi8Yh8CCGx@KTzIhnDH1phQK@kEHkm7nZOWLGpK79B2RHpA4USpU8mT5hTyd5oKGQfxkCV9RJFe4iflBfkyB4BT4snxh5Xj7vZCdIjnKEa6zqjGwhUt/EFxQK63rqfgJe@9EaornryUB4B1wQhNcSgY3wdJDhaLENE@u5vUkiIV/c8mZH49DsG2@USL1T0YgriJY5x5ucRcmQMUQbv7qoOJF4mLUJFoSe5XSFt7KwXyBejF5jXheRVHnjgyxEeA60cKt@aSHZHggjhePsJkl9xbxuKIjLkyTONckmIbKOChEGps9TDwevJVST8HHD1yDmECdVFAQQiRmmwvmr@xHyu8vl90CgDpAwlcAswXp2V3pXvF7Yy07lvDNO9m4FomeSHagzhaMwhTHKYXQQkcwX0dodER@3cHAhnycaQp@S9gO0hWOCe/A2PbbgsFBK6F9NOl5mwPEyMx9RdyWSzpUeCC06piTg8IKHOR0XbXFeecFnVTH60ES22fnoCu5PVnC08hAeFaA/hXLeyvF0G65tjds2KddEF2SpRo5xRk7Ln2E1jx2B3dNSbLgMCw7H1dOD4xfPvoJOd2NjQxV99GicP2y1OKka9uMcMm3MDfuDGcOWTBKVS@PiNV3zjncqLl048h1ewpk1CAN4qUZAfqKNq4KXRfj5VNuFeDxsBKMC1uW4GZgTXAlFHRO7bFvg1QeEWL6yYgoggXgL@E7SaE3FOVmgDryfq1ql7qtaxc1I1aroxbBqghVu9ZexpdTA69Nldlz17bUk0VlUdnDMXj3dPWfnT0vs8OX@5@yr45fs1e6LczzLefJy79nRPoNf6cVZiY1nFPDB6wBwQAl4PbDqVrcGLDuTTq8xgrzv9kac7yj7Knc/M7vsqVu3cD1q2zO7T9rcojuWX@SxSjAcHYl7mSGjXdv3@VVadQBHwk2Djm3h5nYGYWswpu3imLfrNuymDWElHPv2bMsLThexjg01CPw2OPSX5EISXk1AW4HoWiq6UQyvpILwuEgDYExvfAWa7fEIVkNnAnHh89EYPC@dPj9juy8O2P7xi4Oj86PjF2fs8PgUrCdfHb34FPB5dHZ@erT3Er0o4PPjg6PDo/1dcuAZSOsMT@vSHWOLsqBjcMJK/RKXuOlyytAWnXWGYCDBs2uTDrB5LD5wkPvYZsd@azXieQkvLeGH5mhNgIVXhjHrG1zKDNZ8aT@B/NKjazeW02ybUoPGUoT2lhfNFbo9VICMCw/dEcPrV6w8HaJVyDy@1oU25TRsi8n7uOcE5775WVtqywFoSGgJYCOoYANKgZE28Xg8uU0gi5BaveOiSiieGt8UKCwY9UmwdSQvEcbE3hcEitvqjxycDzLyoQPQPThkRLJ@nwdgq6EDD8DWuAOKoke4F4RlRYiBfzxA9szWucPX3d4hrf@yjdBhz6RR7KbIE683qlKTjS@9tbu9DumD57M8dM2L6dVtm6J4FB71qXc6wV1rNQtIHniiuBkH96pBSBmYTROXGsQ2NmdADRt8B3jBu9c2m77HlIKqs3Pc7GM5Nle03@qYDt/SNN6KQ7THNlGTQkHstrZDDfYNfuM0ESDeKjGZjzDegZAKrYfGg5h7d1I0xZ5HugUl2FJ2Xwb27mTgVwEDgLSJkU6deio6x4hg3KYgZcVzgSJx3vZ9NDyQc2NQtyYiBDfhfW2/fasKJCcnxknBvkPKHVQRXhqY5GuWTbcPbZzYahfPfSAXrLfdnm/zOlQmSzC@xwhCY8cGqb0pFCdSo7sLp1J0XCeSaA2oeE6qNSDKh6RKFM8XyUP2FbT18CIl2keH2TFr7pUVWTtL4iLStYXTLyAI80vgsLehSz2F/CmNecd7uphvs1A82LvQ3r9Johp4zhb41UfBJkJ@kV8X04LmQet8tAGxj3KXaGnBXQLeoIaxxZ46wS2xlQfAYBzYtmFc96SaD/349uG77niyZNqdHN@9K/BYGnImzpEHXlsZc7ckKwdJJilOhYm9HhHeCZkFXq8ELkmCGfLrJ3hQBGshDxhxkI/QFZyTOvwFCwlKVxs0gbOIW3pEdYfwVVakrROBIEmPEq2P1Gtlr5AoqqnxzhEWQacSsOhkABkv8RnvP6H@6g64g8XggH8/HNzmwtzx7uGjoB0shPZRedMS82HxbikC6@Fg3y8Ayzu3XwkslD05HzDvJO9CCyk9JM7kcizcHbs4xTd36o7aHoDBvhdnUEKgkdQGDi1RB3obFR5BjYIZC0Rn5wel01Mm8/EJxAW@h0OGhmCDCHuJX3HAd8/aDjE7PRSawsFyKDwFLhNb18IjHwsa80zkzWEVQgZJCnyEzGLyQkHieqJnIRGCdtMTQwwwN5m7m4AHeWUB@BYVdQLzio3FsLCA0sxixnjnY3vRTd0Cb0kuG0f35NOOad5349VA/VEUUHTzj9nCkyKz6@8Vl49zQTpcwLK@GVCBGyBJ4@2YOjuDhHsQUNcna3BBtQRVipvmuYAdC3CHO7zSkxL2352giJC4EM5l4QhbF8KxyBqXj5cDMYd2HmI3YOKWTuHJdyiDR8DiyWU7WqHquNNTJrsgEDLx0ponUaqA6JXbfHjPpTLuJwuhQB5ta8uUm3KQywrOzgrY@fmBPsG9zevT7GE6KeC2C5PS/n6S4r3EREoBzmcWJvAEyOvZ7Op9sKdLEUTX/q6weR8yzT/9bg/G92OQ3sij6X2g3KMXycB/TAALUMe3ygcNZioiiDoz@pSJslNnFM0f5IXPC0FmUBVqvY1X9EymqrLhVN5mQ@c9UhQ6BblThkgTDgvKW80d7N8uTg4Z8r3pLX18eryxYSDcI3j7y/BwXUShSMQJj4lOuln9vkPB@LGkrovHx@g00sIzc3Rojm9o5YVBT1pmixagKQ4Z8W21yWCKgRKhWUUdr/TCSb389KyeZuSjJTw8elZiK6SiqzkxBSn3ZTXCcpZsZ1EGiPXSdAT2GnQU7xMvBz/IQzIACWiiQ3kK4Ua9N2@EERCWy6RjXmz7FCzVmK70plc3HdRukZTpNtzHEJEmX0vHh@qsCfV0fiI@ZM7rOQrESsqaLlNUcMN5XIQ0CYLXJrpH@ikJdayLDZILLgA1U8Zmen1LotI5ST/ZLW9Vkiv1gsygzzWdrjfoXzcuW277qsk6rPd1bVgfvf2GsewawyO@mcdcGaGxXsDTrQrDO4s22VaaCFZkcIcUK17IjJGaDzyrHWfj4Xd@CfXkwUNj5RyegJiiUrbSDagQT8r5hW55vVJwCul8t@xU8nhWz08U/ISRUNDhMXSewFr4gnzZr2BX@svobKvlXLH@oDaCUVJ49oPR2Q/s33GGS@zZpvly2mYsPcLNaniGRHesayW83BgpU0L5R3pEh3gMPO1N08U429KwIQeA/SQIq96Q3iNVepTWBz3fJR@RkIYkxN7Z76RHwamjNE0YQJCyXQmys01wxmEUXPfhriO@G1ozuDRm4FFHNQKijDGJ28kXsoxHADGj4uhVuSJ5umXW25gJvMbuHUVj29v8futb8KZJOtypYfbp4EO6gkZc34BPjxYTMAkSzD06viFB8dFuoIG70BSUT@ddaKO7RIIg@uA2bnZDx5Eo/jYggCP@ERepdDGDKQQrkBP5UT@aO0CFapPjelxFwFOQvFIeYWERNk@vMAZOO74JR5isQBO4P7pGdHJcwSNKoBlku1OMMLzKgxNKaBla2DzEJVUpeRXx0xlHUyLRtCBaEDiCikf3YgMnsmD089yC5jNi@1anA5nmuHg0Rgca6TiuSD8Rpu@VMc1KmHnur93x1yb8de7PMzUOpUP/PQ6UiwaSYzfjcLdMHgdL3kmrwEg20aGm6zpIHOOw@UVhPd13q/Y4cDGsSk6Vocf2hIcW8Xk9o/a5z9JEnJDAQ/8y9xf0nRE1H@ZyIuyTyfTxK4kKsmhvrNhKMkWlumN3dnjnFPogmckML0zn0bG@iex4oxRHJgU7AQENp/Gp2RYLYygJI@A41Gbk4vYTWRfCxI4ynQ1@6PBOw5rRRiJYojQThLghnS@EdMh7KQKCYCKhsaDlFoPIIxF5FAGLoZaCZPmhxTsNHIo23cQLeIzxHb6Cxj6ZuSBcbLbnI57zIS88P4w8iSBiukvybDRNchM89sEdRaEW9CLjtEfTEGcziReRSd4wTYsfmW7iLPdSyCeijCLgFHfwHvoITI8DGAH5zqtC9LyVfplakT41QYTudawh28VRhEmnqaSJ8@i@5fke6jZCnY4wPO/1OrioSILdNZ14Fro5MllcTRlDjCyj6dIRbtzh4ZNoEufHIZLOjhHyNe7/GHt4g1aL347OUKsRsFacULF9Xdp1Rny@AtrMaoafCrfYwOOLojCYb0UzwWuOtx660R3vDNclkMU8kHIkXtQmb99iuhyPhaC6KujScpL0nYFdv9z/FJdrN4z0qhFB2ZVY7U3rq2vjg1KApMAjkwZxNWusSVJk6bfOl341BJhkz7Cj/wJo07rCK1ylXegxKKAHwqln9a@shi5Jp1a4xotwkZRx4RGPTbuDfp3P3YBshVe/4mlfL8lXu4DC8Iv9M18NrtNSWFLCNanxYjJdd99ABAYHSpouLv7SegSe6uf4wEhdywekrKhsMku0tCzyQrJLF@eZABumuMVdLD2EaHBc365DzdBEldQBUHyVY5wYv6g6khNIr94x8ZCvPisDePpljIEgA8FK0aI8SGJN/KPyEFxPHyyhm0HNpID7udRWoLlbfRu47xjBVCsULZJ3qODzp0dn7Oz48PzV7mmJgfnk9PiLo4PSAdv7ipawcR2clJ6yp8fPgLuEi@V8UfwYHOTdM4gpk4e0@@IrVvry5LR0dsaOT9nR85NnRwANwJ/uvjg/Kp0l2dGL/WcvD2hxHSCwF8fn7NnR86NzCHZ@nKRUg2jSOB47PmTPS6f7T8G6u3f07Oj8K0rx8Oj8BSaGi/a77GT39Pxo/@Wz3VN28vL05PisxLBg0sHR2f6z3aPnpQMd0oc0WemL0otzdvZ099mzqYIev3pROmW0ByBSyr0S5HJ3D4aqmBKV8@DotLR/jgUam/YBeZDBZ0l2dlLaP0JD6csSFGf39KukAHpW@s5LCASe7GD3@e6nUDhJuQcrUC/7L09LzzHTgImzl3tn50fnL89L7NPj4wPC9Vnp9Iuj/dJZnknPjs8IYS/PSkmGt@lQ0gADsAX@YN57eXZEeDt6cQ59xssT3M6gQiW/AsRALnch6gEhGHc5YGkBScenXyFUxANVQJK9eloC91PEKWFrF7GAGyb2z6PBIEFA4nm0mOxF6dNnR5@WXuyX0PsYwbw6OiupUGFHZxjgCPdbfAWkA4m@pFJjPUG@uBGIVQooN0nVyY4O2e7BF0eYcxEaKODsSFALoW3/qcA5tOWUFJkssV2cGzC70QmU5l2nKwv1Ft6deZk9FxMqONo/PiiBxMf1Z8lj95fQ6WxOKT6K@kFHE3qCdULBTMOqDVpV22m6eFQ0jMbnN7peK4kXDKgwOmcX0oI7JsQ0CkWIxarVL3arMM49q1bV5ENiTmTjvhhikntRKFWUseNy5Q04v5PLcbRvTyCq@FgsY9I2PFxewJAc@Y/5xjaza6kslWpYIhqewUfAwQyRxxdF2rhQApyRjjKiyv1xkjQBQXZbUANFVALwer2Ks6C475ECuR68nHdjC@8bIg7AnPmsViqFY1jKhv3WCpLhiZBmA3oJxQJ2k5LUPcu6bCnpaHI45NdbrttQVDWIQ2F9GAa2FPWe6DWrNRVdm45PmaVFZaEx3QuG3STBhKvLAmVM1Ivep5Ip@Kr69FGD3HDVDTgnSknRVLSYm1Qe8@i43yjJ/r/2nmy7bWPJZ/MrYNAWAYq7dlNQLNnWjTNxcid2Fo@kUCAJUkwoEiFAi7SiOWfmYX5gPmA@ZR7mU@6HzNTWjQYEWsoySe49yTmxQKCX6urq6qruWiRCBTpP0CSjyPfq8JuXX6My12httjPvP9bveW2hNSCGXIX97oTqndGfj8@4ACwwCqkBKBlJoIt63aijrEl04SsoeIGFKKQ8bdUXAW3rgBKQY@f@2OwTN@PZaGFCD2z4L18cvjr68vgYOCdCu7m7tbPdLuggWd9U@O9b7IeijVKMsBC2cRDT6JOxSp6B3EMrxYgenZA/EXC9jgUxPreaNHqJ4Rq0VUbaTgn5GA43wvwTEzTAswPEg21RHI2HBUWvuStTCMBJDdXF0Vz6C5LwfRCViAbEVGW8pFlb4D/Ytl7@aonrAQkBCYlRrFagXFAuiO/Zx8oQlHQbCrODRWq2omMOuqZxQCddZB2LvrP0S2jbmMWIDRVxvdK0U00A4mEWCktZTUx4Zf@VwoXIOS/F@oI33wi9weNbCUdHwen8KD6MXwMaj3VNPI5Ozpxl0CfS8tmBB1O0tqZ72rfwMN8VoGjtyamxju9hrAYC5QxNBj0r03BbhwPJdkn2rU9LrnXNlIoxOLCdtlCs/AbKzRuOtNJWYUDktwouYXFbOlYJY@1K91FQRd7qcBQKnSk0/SJ8UPu/I05y2t8HhRNaT7BlhOy7FyapVcYVaK@ElNGVuk8wLjESbJqv3ibN3JgTc6EHJpc0C/aeARTI7CzVi7cUpHDg5CAAiRzPNcz1qw3OLnzQnJ7arlTH65BJ7zJ0LNkr1FZxq92zCslcFXWBgj9cy@WDJqO7T6Gi9ZRt5GJRuICLdZfW48jmNtabrordUS/ToYde5USaF2yImiWnhiwttfglTJKxy/R1tCMQRW9W3siVLSOKZYrhy62W2zajW5oDFrRBnwcIaO640QKfTXHT0RI5WPgbimCHUapRZ8atSMLNdcnochxgO4/7dDKCmTHjK9wuxtw6hdlLWrOcx2QUgp0kFoZJjEBkvm4NsE6b7JWGno4pkV419F9OOAx7wEdcqkSNg3kIhKZrfM165S8R5vH9xm0nna8jWg/S/b@cUOjBXsw7ZTiNSHOHXlDTfxwlGFFmOLAPJVgS@0tb0ejoqjpawB/qqyojV0EcQWegAJN5Qv/NSoWA4kumb0gt@3SiD5Ge8EbmPVbiCz7x2tVPb/FJzpk9GBQAB2/wOlXEIAQZ5Sa8wru92gg@jA339SiY9c1jOdhN@36IJ0Akfk8ntO2q0yuJINfz4yhYghTaq48WdWqj43wyvZh0nk3H/nA0HfmgK2AM7QUvQHxc0iPG/xzOplcRpSmhD32jUH@ZPHMEE47ohb/11VjbiPIUxUHomDfi8Wx5eMGBCOjwFs3MLM0zKYhqmA23petsbiWVCmkPR7L4arrtlXU3mnmV@fIYG5BldZC5rGcvxZhcXwz3xvatAt0PFTBg7FpVy3dX2ISlIN4DFNFNQApiBcytG3BzEKgdrIT4pL@o9Cmc3QxD@QTPA0z0ETn0uuJjPkPg9B/hpfQTq7nbMKryQf4CQ9rhw3I1uls7vzP0AMAvAL@5kUcteYRAAX0HKp5PxDKzxKUEWHTyrgpqAqAkT2ejISi241SjnUW21fTn5SpskJEJbM0Sse0WVeKKdED4xsxWTgdYTmfpWj/@aJWskkuRIXBHPIydxmqCDe6y0KTFj/eIfHiDjOmZtOwYQK9CVQ@whMnsMgacJsgchffuFdNq3XfWMgj08oyajAwBjq32S/JxEJkHb1amM2DGdgZ7Ym1QiuJpWLon9lbyjtwgX3m47rnunaamTGzeYr1V7hNqvSU@LtuFLDwZokljjIyagIZQhaJnTeZZJC68Dq43r7O8Aw@rcJaY6OhNRc93n9c@borv0GZUbTR6SRHsGO@yrd@fdGDgndUcRNpkEb9DHKODLKOz5EejqQyaNJbujyGiPoE9g48@YA777QPuzPlZidSsPZaKnqk@peIlIj4x1De6BQJfCgd4/4@ByPiKRDMpjmoePMHArnSb1Kx2MV4tfuAG0VklqCZnIXyKmExWho4onvzA6aDBShM5ETwdmJfsOky8RhjFcZcDBrl07yyrzbM2t7TQLYEsS6U@1JLyaIafJ50FtXILFbDEc1ChR3SLN13cf1S/dCxQDlrg2vRZbEkbFRyMa60DNPCP@amzQBk46UpqplZUeiF0iDXAWgA1ZDgOWHtC6W80Y4rHC3ZZRiDa82sH/6xLDQwAvd3Q2MYqi/4Si7iCbl5trlU94CoJQfFvRL8sRRZ1SV2CBgKGGOp7TWgBI2QS9HgwTcFdTMpLASpzBBW9Ji5LeEkBNhOTwpzviFQpsLlllGjkldgz26jmNgKCRX6ZBBCQWfKLJK3ARpcLi1FiJ388SQkQiBXtM8ZhKmRW0jjUM8cIhEeCVnOUk6ZVaQgF08fNLTf1UdM3fd1rGF8b2a@AHw3hSbWZ/brbSH1NddtqpaumagI@XLPX1EdAhWsCrLnCL/uPnB/M6NnaLNFQMlJShpgCT1CVukK9rfZdZO2T26@SMVR7pu@xUr86nJQjFd/7w7G8LYkU3/7lg1W2kQoQCS5Pgc@UN4XD@iAJrDbu9DgqVHRVKDftAa9U2unA@urN8XEqrmh3qUxdLoPZVqPRQBrummHUlRUvnl@MpvV06fpgPh7Xw6tPZl9168T6MU/0OJo@UQp0ADMCayKqTWdDTiWAMEBRLF0VT0lU9eeDgRmzHy/JcO5g1rikuNtbtP@MtNnFV2/ogIealP31HAeI4zu39OK78lnOlFbUTQjURqPUd7a6wAH04IsBWgLryxJqDPmysqeBbcv1Dq5xA8FUGDRZFAjXvU4MZO2Pg/F4WrG@ns7GfXRFf3CTrXB8bFZocBG85CL30XlEAU8rVvBuNDYcV7GISerYnNqXVGICFWEco6x/EQxfLELHPvnWhl0FhryOw1zHSMcVyx7aroQdv0ezTIcA9r1KX/qh0yM8ZQvDTi8LOHkCiDaalVzVJ1XEpRQjgrO7SyNS88GtUTQAGLpLooCKik7TSyNZUVwj1z5dNAeIwwa3ITBhUI/71UBfpt@PK76LB4P7MUUKKM8T@5szRDqRphUoyw/wifGY/6kKy/o4E7GC5RtM@3Cb72CFDlYoFB73vB@unMPDQ@tRuL5uHR4ewUO1ah0eHVrP8cXRkfUcfh/h7zWvtbXVZp773L2Gl0fq5Y11BG3QAed672L2HH7CNw8dk9BeGKf4Ud17VGk/6nj7B@2ofnJ4hH7j8PS3f/uPv/37f9YP5cd/4Y8j@nHyrS5Uq9Xqj3rXj9Zu2vj75PlZ6VH35FF4Vhq2kcqQ3X85i/yxbxgw1nqFO5x0@uNRd5XjjrbgGEVkLYgWew7843mggf34Iz@dxsnjLHnEsJxJdX8cXvhU3aIWDrzSYWltDZ72vdK/lOjsRN77@v17eG@5yMvJb59Qi6lnrMPXz16@NCNfI9cn6X0QYJgWTJwo1yajSTSCQZ0XVc656olVq1lnVetcg4emBh0umAaR1UwG5l8FSDU6sguh@1NRG/BilI6@@USe70kuoyHJd@ronPNv@aKpPO4/4UsdamMdGB6Wb7O5tLhe4vABXLyF8aonze2ts2qxWCzonFydHrE56i2kvnSOJnWNS3cw7AkUwpKBsXNyeMQFNIjIKBYpY9NajzOLORNUrUljYoW7WDLkeTxvooEUNJvjE27250cZCxU@yoJlRXNyBEDZYHnfKyUAgDy89olxWZyJNgqD3miw1NfumBQh6R32SvTaKluDW05blj3r2jKuh4OkQUAISgEULgYbzTbIyJtC2RFxOx6j@g3ixm2iOpf409YmTbA2Sgmn4@VwDJ05ZM4TXQF3Asy7MlnjifLmwh64ZjcYYCJ0XtE8YYk5KcLdDfAoYtIDBbOPKYrGGBaKBT6@gqSAiLAeUMKRFGUD9EZwxhM2YpkO4BE2fHTk4nRsRIbruKUKQaFSi8qxSnEmfKAcuq4VcknEKvxOLoCJPOgIkvRhybWWugoMXamJb/eF0kLMLoeKtISndGUl2bRW9AUsSJWXeEGGl2OAFCxZo3RWwBqW1vl4cq7Hz1dqEWbEo/szTjhH3bT4jhw4lu5GeWxTd2yObvPhKiW/mvixoDecRtGoC8iKl2qaKAof26/PoNXTUoE7E2rBizpEML4qh3pFmeNTpBQsQnIRZ3gf4NHuRFFBqiBeK@KdGN8NF1M3xZPppEostxvEox4b8XHvDxUvDvGalqz3CbDVHYHywBeVaoKph1MV4EbuKGmqk3YIT2gvj@v/QovePuFMjnmFRYvvAgCkiUPPzmmCpKRFTQnUQBopAiOZIAsGH6QIcxwMR3GqTkWCALDlM4/iRqEeF/k5AmxiN4NZtNWnVdk19plzwbcyD0DGq74Bo911xf82j/bUYHBX49yHuiYPiVy6dm/Th@ZHChwTaljBgD5cvpX0DNHminsdxTHDaJL9NKlaySx8sAdqXEBkflEmHxNqQLhFFifVE8BGK4MNYKeZZZBw4UaqeYOAkbjNnZx4VAa9PF0sEtxi3opeFKRIBDcF7VVy/f/db2oquzN0kYXFB6WQDmCPTswcdCiHbJO5K/AqUIK6xGcD1jibY1A0Np@QHQWjqIx4kRqdajgyXamhywxXSVIKKUQH/DwpmXOZqarGm9Q@S9eultir6Fr5FjmGpBO64nIkXx9InvrtLdUuOw3R1Rv9ulHeTeIcpG0m1OwIyml79QeIHrTCoDQ/enJu8khD6fCKy6sxi2QBwmWqcWqLrmiknGmJkoMktlU4nMfTl/GvL9NTeGO569MvKeMnyAU@iMEiIvhuXZ7gES1g3V9LLUA@MAJGwDZUfhTAc6HAkodomParaHg0XTiNyql9alea23uuTXqylsOKvQg0o2Iv4IBdmDVQdE8KDEjn2u8CZuGz7qjfDyYqHChUld70p440e4LH@dea3UWcZNUmJh7YBi@PqjCJ9EJwTc/hzB9e@vT42fTNzF@@hE2Ifn4@4fl8je19AZsRpgWiL1/wGj3sg6hh36CenNDEvYZILks@SD69mEQDDgZniAs5CAhuIYD71OOP0oM10GCOn88utPRM@yZM6jlLKBEb8p7zxcl5gXPOXmJS1A6/A9p0jKS08kifMpmSRUbAD8rGzHjLNVjUH@NNTzBJ3UOo6LVCeJy5mGtVrDEQaEOpXB8eypRtcs819NG5KDZx76JzOR/HIxnZrWGpcWGlbPpdUidVxuQVKXjpyDCLO2Mc2O7JCFZpossQo0qwIEqYasXQHxW6afx07JgIDaKqcOSJ1ibRR@Om/YG5Yen@QKkaGBjCuLBRyimOs2CoG1C7XUj2WUuP@mFK@UA4ACkIRjmk3MfEmm/MOcYZxtAVxEz05P4WOvvfs5LLb@i2IcGS0kvR@xVEBuZhia5Plu0VqyGX2IZWC5TCya@nl4FotqJOGMqrkbiM4zn@7grrHZpbSvozUKUsh03Z5WFqoaWEQ2WyaaBTCzG0M5uzQGM1hRFTkiCWE4pvPuNZWrphx@hctsFKCZRkmLNCtpKY9Ehz2Bs0cWvzrGgx4tYnV0lvWgKiokBTfcVUZXdLNjZJeo2neskOpmBNy5SmyG4lG2gis@Yo4ZoM7kRUcBtRzZ@HKIYrD0/85VdDUxoBaSzdFAp55KtZh5hmmWtde7Hc4kuEuIdaEM60kSPodscYty4BLNscJo0XyX5PCcNl63AIbDEtC7OFtZ@8Y62HFcgo47WsD@LYKn4@w7iuRZCuCvA/xtgFLnWJBzqpExAQWesFXYh8lBAbhG99GiFe81a96BbEZqhe5Ew1zZ2mS53coyd0Av0F4j2zQbyKGdxywMINhUSOstURJ7a7dz/a61YcS6fGl3skDRw5OZRm9lwOQzQmv@uUul6UaAqOBc1brvUzD6jprKTFexCe89SLhQcAAksaGNYNOqPa63LAGwUwDB0Uko9zEzMs1g/VQfcf6fxb4VjZKggFaAGhoaQDlM8oCzFPsEgI5ExJC7T0OCoBqrUrR24viahG4iKhNkXJagdvyladeyCkZ4V26chKknjOYuNUMffUVJ0QWcXcapaDUS7xNIOujoIeHoTrU6rINc6D5dihDm1LUmgAi531dJMpdmUOZ23NEtjoyDojY@Qq@ilEMRwpZJxOmDlnSReYEL4kxMuWAstES31h7vkDF5ASyepcyxdEkL0mckhyQlNP8D6faMznY4eqfgg/5AwxzTi5EE6Io@rwIwk0hZ@K0Cw@7yBSOtD7@6HSnzQT9yVVSR29ihZ5L95p8l5s7j3LqI6nDbj74N9Rj31Nybkx2X@ssukA/ID3XzqmgH@YQMlfIdaO7MDto9iVdNcPEr2uFsUdztyt2S/qcWJy1@/DdgzMljybKqAnxmSDZBl4Vga25OT@kzZMpaRz98IKQcVEULKamdRO9DKLFDND/VWe8YSpgbgSP4DmyLyIvAnx6mraY9902KDw@4A800mvbbJahAoRVzzBn@Li92DAkfIGspJ5BFa5I93KGAQeGgTLWEczP76XiJVcybHBvk5en6XDqFawXv50kew@cln53nJZsUxn2uVEPCsXQ5AtNn5mG7@tnJYc0EI7tobcxoVKB/ikcgCKYYLGaGGcHOYL1zKv3H6@2Pen@PJH3RjKf3jxpazR30sLMeVEiOnlCjFJAanVw4M3qqfLE3uAZTshDbksYg/3N033B@tG9TfN7Y@TgVtJOak8pW7xdU638dVUamhClQ7p/DG3I@S1vKbPbVnb55Zze0HzfCfb8Maf2/A/9jZc17jAgJd37DTG1P859/8Ic48hFMe7jd1G51e799XvbJOw7Mx9q2XZD63mwUc7p4vnjdPF3ubnPxTj4kGr/vUM/sbFH4rbu0V@hAf4taF@vSseFPex2PZNcVn3PA8epZXDY2jl4BPdJpZa7sM/B1uq3e1l8aDqUfUfiwfb8NBstQCS08WLvdPFbgP/t9t/JPHDvF3RwseqVkOKqyIbAt8Fiok8qeXTKGnymbE7vEQSUOp4@oAUd35otEoAo/HMorXbEFkFCIjjP7wLJAXUZYCpu/TxFMUwiSmOBntcqPgPYqvHlWAF6C5c@ENd0G4volcSc0KFm0ApIQHaOn9c28ar63MJQ6EB0IEnSMxkU25QLxzqGENs4d@Dxke2DkzxxJa4FbZp8S93m7Ir7squ@L9FK1zGF9NJKyewetF6BtMVB9Z3EcMSTUZhGMQs8Q@DSQBbMh6mj6Yo6GCmtx7mxRuPvmfzvyeqcatHDXW@izrsm8MN1cKlZT96CitrdEla0XtYleoZ78e2N9UvYNyYMwz9ZJR3zXAUX8y7FBP/zWz5Mv6cIlHUMa52zFEp6iDLdeuXPhoOUCT5CEgMSgA7mM0ndcotBgIb@spg@PdL/3sADfOZwtD6HSiGh/3fO5Q8NApCcnFZDAY2ZeoJxv3XQejPfI6ahlbzc38YvMTAMDAZ0YWNylPR@oyca2IzOq5WlgjjIIdLSqYqR7Ai3h@VlPsnoday0N2YMsbY6KcuTIh4t10jrwmoZbNrAWWpHkyncVKevcZ1BfqZrkExwWCS2DUELweTEQE3x/GvKyDWLUteEBzJT@k0eUEdETQza4SZHHBUwWR@SbSjM6ueNJ@cSdw0r2lkuCaL190nktXcthGhOE1y2NzcxS9ztr2ke8mChA7Q4wDBmiGBgjwhc7otvARNIYqm3e8o7g9yJViQSH819U2WPZnRwyMedk@CoU@84qo7iqlAfxRRAaxZH74H2Z1RVEmRanc@jGq8FsixYhRF82BrZ3eTAKIdXxXtT3upoq06tDzzZ8s6AXcRX471KPbiC2scvAvGYr1CYFNEWV6URGeYVMufj8msZdsl0gFUpkYKWHD2Kvzu@YvjTw/fvHheATFlC4tH5JakyzoGcvnzOn0fjDFSA5MRVuHlW@tubzKRO1Gl9BRP5Bj0pyba102AVQNRVMM9YBQ6JY@qiZ0FN2yFqLZPhhV9HX41nX2vAxfjckNQ5pTtwFbIVSu/WESXrgj7KiIJpgIbQB0cmPLcno2B8dwqtJJXAAaEu3VioMgx8k@kXHv/YbWq19QTeqoCY61WD/iQxX42HoHiWfpiPklx2xKtHd8qAZPD639mbQ9LxBdqdtu68FCPb/e8Rlv77b1z5u61zoo8QCgcRtyb6dFSzZ8zF880GxDikpWzcpn8n/8uue2bJIjO2IldjP5vvfdU8OIaM/UXnC7VKUU9mKwYqr2vxcEifsbRJr24rSt0p/2lpL1/Blp133lv9hE67jXs1evrPc/bcK@hy1mIUShDYIbBG2jRbeO7QeqddhGrn55OMAdyGV33vnn16ccw5WgnFkTxybdn5Uf1Sqnkum0cgu@Rf9/zz1/9FU/5Z26NTvuPZ9NLwcvM153UYLYvo5PGGUFfsXFodVyFwDmHQSyjj46Wb/zhZyAtOSUfUIBmSeQYB5My2vfFv6yNtkkoc2F@EBNHnp2eXNu9HnpU6mIWDNp8VnETee@coduO4c@F2cUWdOG1WtR6DJU8tGrKYH00gd364zevPvVK@76FrXo5q6K03tXEAYRCBOPgq0PMiJQiHeAqRFUxe@sRwcB/6yX7ID2W/bp/UGrf3KyE51OO6QrCTykh4L4zrwjFzbzbU9qeJVSwDAMPX/DW9pcXb@wK1MUQLPhygtvbkpgWO7F6qg8mN@QUtAUuX2MZz9tcW6N3WGUeeV6r0XAxIsoNtBZhCnNolhfWrH0z872@oxHph6OchD2tWqvOjixRvbndamztfDSdwRbhYU70tQhYiIday7tRvFwD2TDwVPKfNZCTYTf1Hm6Wdz8fHf3zN3uvt587ve4nTbtifxeR2f4sNAGY@Vc1FouAx84k3isBgZ6LPb8e@t9P65v9Rg8kz@ZOP9jZCnYbG7u9rWBjr7u3t9cbbO52@3s7/s5Wr1vHeONUpXY5moCUZDP5Y7eD@3W7SjDbbTX2BoNmc3unv7U32Gs1NjY2u7tb/cbm5mC36W9sbPdbu9297oeltgSeAjBYxXdx78hy4MerhbvCLd4utd3/Aw)

`document.documentMode` is used to separate Internet Explorer 11 from Chrome. `documentMode` is present only in IE, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825157/internet-explorer-11-detection/21825207#21825207) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_documentmode.asp).

The code in polyglot:

```html
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:257</script>
```

Note: `window.InstallTrigger` is not used instead of `typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'`  because of Grass.

Answer (score 2):

## 264. Haskell with ScopedTypeVariables, 12400 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]xx  >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4o'6o@ ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRqTzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPs
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:257</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #a",_"[];l{t}8;rext7095?1&&1PLers$/  \nu2FAC0::FloatV$ f Cr=B51 16 4 6>E>83nt:k:~-<le._ngtbontgerminPrsharExu Uatafint 22w;e!         $
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...    ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak) )int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__ ((destructor) )int g (){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num (a->b);instance Num();instance K Float;instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B  )?4;d(B _ )=r$ f 0$ f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a};g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ) )-(-q?6+70+z)); (!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0 !61,{-_-}last$ 172:[u$ [-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIsPkB3ua97CaHZHffOyAaXQAKQDWBKlxUgQSazY6Z8casxlJ45fGsYzRa645kyyutHWGtY72Sw1I4Qnp1KPykH9Dyy4ZiQ/MPZs85mVUogADIHkkRWySq8vNk5smTJ09@nawZbvuXv4zgw06czqjVcTzmma7HGn3ryuxrbHfEnhiWm0mvShKG2um3Bl3T9tycFGE6Y7Z5zQ7tutUAN@Y5l6ZtvTP74JdmrNd3Wn2jy7y24YHFglhs3@y87773WN3pdg274ULIVcZODPBsDuqXzKi5Xt@oe5Zjg9caYy/sjtGtNQwGIcx@r296BD7DAET9kuJM@qwz9szpuyYmXzdd10HHDca2zG7PGxXBkoUQRt9yjnaefz4VeZOxzw3IWa9jDqfyoqfYK8vsN6Zi6Dp7eX5wMO2aZl@qjs0O7uZPX2Uv@q7RMabhr7GdgeccetPuGbbTMm2DpbVNLT3tuc52@8adKBusbxqNptUxNcuuM5W1zU7P7DN0YU2nD1XmmZ1sKpuq7oxjanWMmx17ToEt@A8z@i0XPJ0rE4wm1ETPMhus2Xe6zLDda0hJ30yNwyPYzUlyqEMGgdDYWxdiN0zm2lavZ3rcE4pr9skbUmYdy76UOPWd9J3GoG7ZLQhnAl57A4/K5Ep1iFZkPUHDGhpYhLDAg0EWzpyuGa4LF4gXcu32zLrVtOocOebQM20XyutqzIK6u7Y6HdYwOxBhDL2eYK7DBm7IqdYx2lpdkxC5mArrXnaYxeq9HuNeUAzI0kEqy8yu89Zi78C/03bZsNdlrtUFb6/uNJumyd6ZvTZEZ92G1HAkBk@9N1WywLZsQhjbhNLtnXwNePMQnXYTstZgtVA4yAflmUps2A6gr89so8upod4bUekBTBCj6Tgaujcc07WjHrt2@pesZtYNLDYm5pqtpjHoQIpWE6sD6MByWdeBL1SizSBbENlDXCBsTEyaWRBMxq9eswcNE6vXQXKBuvZr@bpvAH30XVGPntUF6rC8qMtMw7WQY0EU17QbRBm9gJc5UNpwpbMrCxoeoGLQJ9iu2SfSJ7gMSwEgjYBWleu@5QFFYCl22Ilp9Nl53zRjnE5Nt270kErDSUJiDqbgYUE0IsytrWjp@CAKBMpjaEYPCLK/ev6dLySDaQW2XM3DryDLean0fJ/dLF@gmfNMIOJeXzFirPCBucmLCxN@Q72WbPVvJYAqAVY6LOn0vKSh9iCDqgcZTBpoRJN6ldZ6nVDCbGuqDkLNhodqQG0AE2AvE1Sy@qDfR@4@RqpxCYXuOHYL8AmF7Q9sXuXrKagCoL@Gm2DmlYk0wOvIuSYMn7eBQuAfgoY4C@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@0Bz@0j7dYNoB4XOzUPRLoEqxFdU08InIV44rUZBa5dA0bq0xE1Sd7kML6KjFJAGDehyZZsNkINGZgAtGXPvcONOw5KB5Qn7HmAddiYqNGCqoHIvCA7vCA8JXKZLNKlDQwFodVMllVrFjQCbG7A0wXNh8oGwVfTPAxA440kxHu6xgh7NS4ajBsM9mkG6wJ76I9Y3USeA8zH5B0KJjKg9ueC3MucJkup6Uxmso3daWJeP7mjfheY9LvkwpaEhQ83JmQ0rAlidsewWwOjBfzCsSGKUa@bPU8wKiiJ6wErmu5vyFEVnafmtqXlJ9NpUyfii0fjNJDJ89oTXaGB3EWI7SrIZCj68bEAa1h9YEvQk0@lDgGuphKX32CQiQy8kedkwZcAgMjMoVkfeMDVgICv21a9DTSLubM5X@Sd0HTy4BROHTi72gySxszoxcdpSUsGTpiNuSBUrNG7cKBzRVDFCQeq/LDDYsiG250B2AmyCB1ByFVLGhrQ3j0wu47tzAAKiAzAYpBJH14PIImdoVAMHZcvdlFjDSTloIqgzoBrQMsH@mt7Xs/NQT9hee1BTQNKSZ73R4fesY3EkvT6I8tzuLnWcWrAll1on0k/hWR9ULOGUwUit6AO37rSFQhgTZcVoOf@ZgBUp0SbLjBMct/DwCEvmRg3geBvGQJSIA0QpTRdYsUHwFTORnZdkSeIUk4wGduuHAMDRgxQ8wUKb5PZfAtO07nEYOHMaEkMlXT7dTKoIZkUwWNwypb0aKJoD8yj9EiW4dU0Oq4JX3vQ6aB1YHMup3BZIcZupEePgLUplJzV7XWsuuVVuS97/FjIFGwJxngoNjVRZopBnEdiMK0BQ4EwovvhoTXPOSNhV4lBQR7dTiRs9vtOn6frtfvONSMHDCaFkbrndJG7s1ckcKEEDcNay8bhvehLqSs1ZooQQZ9K8nI0qr11LFu5iS4tLUVz0SL0mEtL22DaQtM2muJg2iaTSiYMp6GJYiTIhL5lioFuleht2Yc8jFWwOQyxt39n9RSjnMutVhJGWRffNH5jgGfoMSC0ih@AE40VCmiMxeTiNRRUqzUnS7@Hvd5ZvW/1BBK@MK4MbhdYWCU0QMU5fRwY5FF4WYyTbqEP0gUMBuptpR@9KKcuKhc3F434xW00gbFjeaNQg0JBekpXa/WdAYghsfJaTtUrsVh5FYSPWiGaiq4oSlaFYRyMRGKfZWNxg2NbiZrQGyoXF1FAqsBPud7uE7xhIh2LBaiCfKDAA7K2EtVuspB@LVaJxaMQNxZNwNCtEI0CZuqIBJcKjW1pAkHHp19yxOzF4xI1bxiV4u9OdwpuOOidjH4yePcOeReHUQsorDMwuJTXEwGSh7YfVkPPqUGr71VrMuSjE2l87jT5qGgPX6WjA8kcUm19fnxQOi1QMm3DvQSZQm1h2CTIyoCVfkMDbtAZNExpVhhgG2Cqj3OCcweYeKteZ6rDKJha55kIdRd1Ngca8BoSPB2mdrqTRXDbkN@9iTIQEHKnmIvkl7qfJR58Zp6CJA@AY@@dHU1MkXUvQZ5gdbeDwrfa5wUAa3KFOzboE4wxcuyQxmg2CJhAWyBfNoK5ANuxVeSF/nDOCSfEJ0QgBLmhtIWShDURBgE3rSEMiSM4nyJEf5RYUfrfc2wYnJraK@KGMgNGjrNVpjZT/j/hgpRWd8etEyR9MPY6Rh34/SS4C5ldAEDgQMnkbJ9Y/g7g6cEBjePvKyOIUnXDRvw1LBqnDiy3jeiFsQT2Av0mYBUHqTi5Q1g7ZHWQcluAaXNoeXzUCi38DKM8NVwlhuOkHT7OQCpDGRkz5c/ckQDr1GGEb4KsjL58uoSV7Cur79iIZK0EoIEV5bEOpoDPQi@Q0c7OYXp/Pn5nAQeM3XHWQ7gNQ51Gbt2F1mU7HaflsBUIgKSpaZywD22c4YRRjmf0oEVZ7whBOy0HhvqTNGiawZzp@mow3jQwZJLCa2@hF2CzCz0OMKfMZ4ffLYEYomdSKci/b0vRExQyBGW6jOhYZ@MAYhWgg3SDNflds9ce9SfIyXXEvIlHk4fUMPlMlgEiJORKtPB3FDXcyLkLtHPfq@GbZpW9RGMCnLwLj6snSj8hrfBmAyWMTDmjq4@KCaB3Knxcv8i4LpITfCuYKlCbXcczki81YNH4klBCVi0mu8noUjSpqviWyYuliyzZMK@SyKXGkIclsz4T9tA060n0xc6N@YaZ6PE956DmAh6bXlBM/vVxEMScLn8rHkfGTrkL0uaZhk7@vD0wJbPedph8AUOMcMlk6CDaMFZWAfMgAOK4JIgmVoQkzxnAsK5hdqyu5R3SnH3HxrGLRsxbQ64lfPeA34wBnFgmCOR8wmHcyeC8@riPsls8/ClwcoIKQ3yNo7RvNpIrY2jPHKcP40qX6TSnkA5Q3xUeScftNTRvCAB4rBL1767fzz8/3i9VT3bOnxaSA7ef7Fg14BENs9qFwWwHmsOcB/OGM4QloB3LdroWlMgH@e6yc@o4HhcecOHgYU8EI/owjvarR4e7pzunX4vMUY9udQcdA/OYW54KEMA4ozALwdSdmgOyhT2YCwmEi@Pd4yMfyhcvjg53qvulk@PzEJi3g45l6MNk77I1r0BfYBCmaymO@uNOY3JFh4apE7MIgtngmCvPYGzKVBXeKrrxRHFUpqEHisjYPaoqzgIbOM/dZ2k9tbnZqBnZrLneqK@tbTSNZqOxltazmWY2k86k4LWxvmmy9xRcVc0hzdyAic@K4AQSpgGZp4@urfkSDgxF6yCxjGbmK/BdkLl6JmNurG0am/XNzU0jvdFYNdLZDdNc32iupVLmup5q1rJ6dnVh5kLZQNFqbOvSDBC0OpwsIE9gfgp8JpoDzzzIeteskU6n1@uZ5uZqupFJrTVqm6lMtlHTN4zapplqrq3qab1RT@s5Py7OqAKXaEOFoVRpg2jqe6k6eMYkvzMNVzGtMvrL0ILhLK8ii@n5y8g4cBAea@gxEIvIODUr3DPo7i8h4xSNcF9H9y4uII8lWbIGjiJglgLiOrLWr/mOm@gYrCBPrK0CqxT8c5b//EgC8o2eukXg17gGHSrfja6T@5XXbE44p8n5UsWurDN2XiVnvgI9ufYrCnvHa2bgAN4aweMr1zPh3fGaGTiAl@HwcMV7Nrgpn1lBA2DrBAxXyGfCmvKYETCAtEGQwqvqY78s@c1bUhdpzfSeGymAvUmw@Wp59S1fraiKxXKkZt5AzkESO3JAfj6ycN6@OdFipGAEfiHJ/jTC5ETS2Cc9XiZh6tXs9R05DIgzA8u@dGjgHJiqKU3PIJQARPeyczdmE4Ya9JoIeidTd314/9WtNek1IwB2utMzc@RB056i64eu1kie0gcnQGflYHIqdyL5mtkcwCgoWbNsNN8TTN3MUshmrWbNCwqYwM0H/ndGsBw7HcBINK2tabo/7MWlE@DZfB72/PCYAtYMGsRNzv@zCeR7g74HscT3v36vAZVwt4raxojGgoGhapvXRB/NuTUmoqKFXrNrd9zrE2LIdB/IuoFLrkYnMMwGTbWvqm2j38Uhl6huIFB8ASUsoDWecz4X439nJ5JjhOTJdQZmW11WnxGawk4tifDEaJDdcYwGoYEPhS2TIvWxsnk1mEM@KAwJPNDzzEtoxsoFG28V8NoDb8DfuDvgvmq0evhb1ERFyFTGqOkmiMhGzTIXVHrfuBw0HBUkPSoyZmx9Rthx6WmyTm12jEturKJxdvF5AftWqwXyhPjOC3bdhrENDUqT1/S5jy5ce@D21BpUlgcNh2zUFLoLUuh3@HteEEvsnwsM87Fmdej1gEoPiIvIBUQ6QjRuaVJDSLOm0NwxaiMcqrc/ncowQRJwgOcU6vF4ahW7vWDtN7wVaX587Csp/ubm7Nh8MxVHyazhVZJvolL5BDKVWWyruqdioeOyukZHTTdCxrkc3Z86HptmBKV5G7XeMVwgLU9Uh3kF1UevReSOPVMdhl39sWkBsY@z428BmLeaLNiWaNV1p2O52LQ78zjo9ALcOE3czkav0JS0NQuxDZKZ3LYamGbzBafu4VLuHEJ7AJfjq6i4Th2iHM2Zh7S6c42/uaJF27ky@Xt2R/duZq4ewLHUDpGEVZ/ZozTq91Eqbgei12w8Xs7Ml1fvzHSfbAP@FEd4gPZAunatjuOyM3ovQkurD9H4ezZFhzFoGbZK60Fh8@xoIlM9polZ1jn1anRaTmc920oa8Jpb@YN@E/sE8X0o9wu4l67fz718@cixdfGdy/Yvk/3L@@qOlib6uGgfMi7ogWexMLEoOb@AMJLAnTizC3eQylJMLcnHy/MqoF9vXxsj//sr9CzzsOv3LL0Rydsg/mGEzSwYvD6XwX@V1NYWp9Z4GHu6A3bjvkKEKveyY0JHRu87VcrSKf0TY@ip1MOZVbMzMAfmTF51XHtr4v72BaOQh2cqJYqxLGY7cUYI5zqDUO/E@PFBucY@HG0LGYzRsaCR3yvpzOR3PZDRezjkPgHDCRruRmzZg95E5U6M4uzTxZhr9/yW7TQmMok@n8qRsvfLUxOCvGvSb@Hgig8GcW2rsJZKpYR8E5q/nrAsGnStBnHfWvw9kTC5jFMeh8XZkH7IODuN8VQqVL116ao4qfkw7pSeNyNAgTc3k7Zlm94I3/OqZBa3rTlO51OqEJhuw0L5DaRSXPi5ryrvyEZiNxgbz324OHNSa86b9eAdkhidAvZw4L2IGsJTrw@qZhWXrKGVtqasi@eBQhO596UC3TxNLvGtE535gqeYUdG1rLaxsEVycdapmR2Df4bra4vgbWqrC@EFIouQk2ltC9fD@ArYeEU1MsW3eiNAltWAQU7b7JpkXTA6MBpvB67/mRto6OBvhrdG643z4vUsYBQ2vidW20KilOfYMCzzjH7LxHFNB1fFhes85uzPqs9E7mHXaJn8XNUi7jme6sCtw3w0ODbOnvTI8V1ndYjGt34sJgVoTJfmyPW/MwE@G9WhPgfd@6fqptp9nTYq3dfQteTMxYR7ZEW77bTtttnmO4EC27zmARTp8RNxiwoB@W@164z4U3iXUhizHafTeQhmkT9ybuk4zZl5KuE5rQZE/SS4I6MGHuJz7xQg9PWEIOr057WbtjmALst1PKdnqmSbF7SDk0X8PY@L@os7v@os1MIZAsCI//1V4d87Nm0Zjtfr0afa6wxcelFUlY7XzarKA0rmIVRheXzbEadbs@XU6m3rvizVTMOzrcukPyPErQtHtr0QFiym7qOz1rEAef2RhtRQCPuf4edwXpWKySXebQWG2XWcY3uDfn@EmPAch7kd53rMHyb3TwTTuHz1AQ3zciBWBmd4kzSAO@v8HWQLlkDEQuJcAiMhHAVu1UyBwKLPnVGa2N4Zah2rq/w1Ty6aKj9lKrR@@ylTomLbA00OWqGZW3CfoJ@JxeiZnZXdHrTcu@yOT9g3QMTC18ya3mnhmeapiuaVCj2QYYvPPHynO0ncvg3fKtTcwFy4upJZuLxC4fSOajgWfKrwgToczJ0261g9l7@Z2kzPFBjuLiHfDTWaPWwW9dMwm3wtBE33SXpdp4@HiECkUOt9063jVDpyZC4/ce5jOy3gzGqHjQP7YWcW4e6q9czqD3o89avnZsvA7ZVHFu607MygCoA6vXh9H9DvDAzX@s7A8cyZ8KYXsO8D98xoWfWnE5j3gfkYFXvw@GeC7NHpLvKv25ZL5zd8w4I5JyQyTrZIZ1WQ92eN1qam64OD0YunVUKCktj7zdRD5u8RDwy4YID@xsy0Zs3EOz0aN47ItGgS3vJoZlZ8Z1LV7E0Ai5K/HnR7A1d8ZqdO@3TCU9TdS3J3ry1gi@o3wI1Z2@h4s6exQzOzIHOJTnJsnCeFf9fqOC323WyKgYgGnTYK5TMIbhe66xPDgxZhzyBgSvuBC6U46aH2ecG@AZowV5lq2Za3eILH8wwYI/lfLAzvbPAUYvII39qTT4Wgns/GyNFCCQb69lG9g4fiP3UkwNkuUOEZHVpHY3BuPkz3IhlzTwD0exfbvA6P1xYu@uSwS3XsgafiLv9Ffcr6wj4lx4bZ9RBpMOU7pWcvYmEKoe2v98mhJgwEB25nNDbN3XgwRXiWDcLafF48GdofTeybpNLglDZq3hNnp4enp4jl7zuzRjwnI@h9Hjxkgg5k0N0367jyeG/az51nILpBV9YDpts9NXHLwBQvmR0Rox05daMD@Gncm8wZgZ3RV4wH10bPrEH9dsam2bLYLMD7hmfMkZ1o4pBGgIHpXlqxOjWz/5ZmBEPmeYPayQw9NYc0DJlPMLwVql69zgVunJabaCPTaztuz3Fs/iYmnIKP/mwxs4HugV4PX3HXcP/yRO83c5A2WdrjK77dxGzwg3vzits3a06Hv7EIc9iBbfHNBUbfMt3kkWUPhuTGVJDdZg9z@DbelLaB0xxuGxrbtQVj7GB3L25W41uF3amRFIjEV4ZLS/6zxzQTO4kfvquobfTrDq6dCcMnrpyFjoTdw8eDrdJ8a0INKmUIDM2oD3y9AvdktdOtdek1d0wSqulTs4ZH7mp0ftQzhrOEyMmjY8Jx6vCWz9Kw4a8z5QRGPbH7O7LpIdskxq0evYihX88kEz@555ZZf2fE7uGlQSuiueSkQSPamQ1pchMciDkdU/XauMcy6XnzGMZz63LQeMBal7@AMuiauGY9uXIzl6gct00U4cxepQ8Ybt8UW7dxlyA0fd@MXFfdmUuyCB7@j3e/SELHXF1fwxP8g6HaAnZ2/74AyPygb4vPQ8juxHG9pjU87qEaJ6c/j79gsTIQBT68OaBpZV4hoD7tQYfPd7RCO7q6DRrfgTTYdMDUIRbumappX6mk4mjoL1f2DV@PzNw6nN4cqt@zO/TaDdYDwUPtufRN9tyTw6Pjc63n6gtmDnHD38Dq4OoeZcV3gwKSaf4U9RntVVssb@4f75aOdpjSACbj2LF7QosF0V7bqJmekTTmjnPQ1/RmC31Pz58dxceHlpmy1@47XTMW9t47O0tARtgXZzO9w7EPgLqbznBu9MOSrsdmkN8Lm5YD57G8GSnNg3RuwmgViOkpPz97r8BUd3pm43zUM19Cb4hs9y7pi4NIpDMp0K7hJsQROXCz@uIYvqv5CsDEeULqHvyTLeBo1OsDnMmCJqYxCqgoRjwei0ki1lPnmnVRuxBGculY7KXVy7OUb0SKaIMEQOFRMYDClg22VWDp1RSLxfJcxwaQD7SBgZlnTcsHveO6VsuGLPg5IPVIqDqFa15yGQwzPB9uucyWb4a5VE6/ZQUm52RWqfAc40OJlIY90m10yqOXl41KYTmqqtHl6IWdY6loENzswPB6ZnBjIixkFj8iwwF@ud4zh5SWBdjMc9Uw0O2h2qW2YTc6JhN0BOXvcwUnXHvOOW6X/os/aAhtVKR1rWu5RgcQggrlgKTbzvU2T9dHV69noDYrhHHdxqlwTF3d22EwTPfqba6ECqrrxcF5Vqi2EdrrwHLCJzuDXHDKwRVXPKbrccLguQmOXIqEg1h@oWD8N@jaIHA1vLarsTOLTuAO@uMzNUKnn@31cVmlkWCHrGHizlQ6WE2riB3HuaTDVpiTv/gDrtCHjleLY69@8qTIK5QinqLWSYtOve4MINc@kHdm3xFBFESyUfcGuGZPeuTIPYaHjknTEFC76uvZoWS4sp29nTOmllgUNdShXoy81VSWd04/f1lOVQofWDdp/tfvJWM3AnHyZ@rmuisnmB8kf4uEFfbOgPfYN8rk5aHMEwzOnltihHfN6wO163Eiw@PnPo05Ts9vNjhkINVgATUKlRsKmqmefYU7XVKzRgRrXpPCHTrkaGMfRmr@XGhgYI0RaN7qCsvKgC8jq2cey0CCqLTIABNXzEansVF5DEZZHrL3jPoZGDPomRTYOCI7qK@oW9j1zy2shs@TJPfN2oD2VF@ltXSmQMVZrha2imQCmcRBvWHl1xfDdEq9GG6UKjAKEki9uBh@lkp/BVh3@hDrcRJbXun5/s2yVky9f@8aIybLt9E8P/8CbGL55uTwpHR2vnP@4gxq4dZnbQf8FJzPa5CK6GBr2@mQRjbACw5HPoH/BLYxG0Sdn7GYFD6CSEEFrmVVXubGEGuaiH1P9FnxXTPkfzeA4GlNi0lBzwBUYBCxIdaw8IMe6pVjIq7QjUVUZmH/gQ0oQAyeMprBSwlVMisAslRA1gNRxeYXdpu7PQRj90JZjLbtmUEQY0F65cCfF3EmCm7/XsrdM1z3715uDmVxuSnMgnJD0MDVj3Owc3j04rQ0Gc3v5InrFjYz4uwtZ87Y0viQxlcGRiovRERchi/ITKYI3Co6M66S1PSuTSiWYI71Lo9MFEr5l6UxYQJmCqgVtyKkEEWhHKB8g4LI9NFgGG@Esuj30SFwN7yIARM4kAPQfsY1WUCOkHZXDR@/GAhVoMtveifExAW/jrph8SfhtzgsGvbRA5e3uTldVdDruAz@Q72Sb0pX2JCJ7kyvMJWl4dcx7RYU2A8by/M@ii1zRMjLPO9ykF/Uygl5arw1aOWLjryII7XQS3eMnusLgxH23PHMHPtm4JDaDp@ZBPIFKYQ1uBJdqlquGpbUgYDcDcMMv98ieIcHZwWUzrhoRvw9THMDGzsqCMT12YqD9V4f9T7zE89csSRHuSN0GPpdJc0euUJnWSAluOzKci0QwqkSmijjdIBTYmlEwVEnMilsYTsdF2SSBnTfIKF42NWCcKLROUx@GFO1mRwBmtQCkTHBZAnDuoW7Ou2gK73GUcEbHnmZwhFkNwQzurWkqoC5lmX7CpBzqBGZJk5yzOsPcJtlMXonip@FHJnUttfthALO0O55YSY//uZvc42eFx6YfyTMw9Qu2H5d2Jpg/g3fR9fB9s8CWxpsP@a210mssrtqDMf5DDRSzD25CsT5RL5TMGQMvipoKlBQ5VjdLw9PmFtHDcNYoV0Y243rCtmMP05hVhco44oqGoPzFMb1OIajlF8CnQBxAZGgjINiDaVn9isKarTLJZOYcVwQ02i/qznke1BIwd03A1TsCpJYcj2zvqYnIZPqlQ@QdO608PgdBxiL5YAxSldWr/CmVmdbW1tMdutGxyys5zmBJJeN16vymyCjyxBW4qOFMoM4EGUcA/yKIpqybMT1GEbF3iyqR5GxNRxObyASKmSAIDF0tn0tHSBzOgJVQMy2OfRIbBr5oyDg2rYT0ujsA1IBEIeN6ken2@T4SB3O4oZaqRauBvkVBqNpjJw8i2LLr9mFd2FXhBpaBtT38xn0a4P5n8zQTcspC7UQ3VWKqkyrNMXSsCdntoOT4QeQW6akk@nVpL4eC1GoLEBBfrG9vweQ0MKBY9RN663Tc3f2SodfHJ@c3VGORSGj08GiLFrcil@oWqJcCQzRIN@TSN09SJ492z3wURnO1Xg6GkOM9xdPZ3NWatM5nZP6K3568W7a5HEnIT31UMA0l6Ue0D79u9DHvslQwD1@eOpOqkrs5rZc2Spe2JE7yb@fpfA4oq0gcYHpwiV1x9HpbGIWg8sNzvFyA1fzj@breC4fD2x6zuX4lL9wCHnw4D4U4ACSlvRDzWOekIFjPgM0VkeT5rcruMT6@CwRqaENchQKee7fw4BNa6w9UagNbBtuu2PVJOjAG6hKkyv98bXaBOqCNLfXsTwlJtEUSAHFIGBiiriNYZgbarSKrpDSY4KVYIs0EfrwYhI0AoAXPRm4bXbi9EJzW/umbzoFaYTtD/gSq8m@GHQhXJM@pyayWBPkExUiA6KiQVb5qBpallBEOIyjskdIr4zqCEXBtW4jowxjWtscNqwWMHAlloCW/pkOYlWgKgELTcoJ7SjwOI7hz/HQWhiln6SPcjgGbpQNzbIb5lBBBUu5Csin6B69fnUVjcl3aICUYu75avSmtGP6DdHwRIsYa5acamybwRUMU@pLNzdRSRVqfYBqgRTPvP4RGKF/Uppdo8eUAaltdZnGyKpcKHbC9foxpha55hebxeM0qoYPeYDUjEGbZCLCYQrOQyrJAtQOurp2Az/vrB4r65pWATMlEmPLOKO2B105zkXFJBglQZQcgS1g3bIc5ohTr8YpD@Kgv0R65BjqLp3hTdpGabLWQVxQqVnxcUj/1rgFcqxubuZEbUyymk0GZHGXy2tJADuDhfhSKuBXHOIHrKE2fry2AddwgC08@dK0bRMQBDTTNaAPNgZAZP1Ywr9@JTHW3k4pRHgWnwqtAJDRSa3upehNBxf6l5N5mpzJ30Kf@uYCO9Wm6FZHyf8xqSXzN8pypzBKgqATKyrL7YIeX12Jx5ftFWXZxq7@8WOc07ldBkmiqsEQaQiB1OVOLA/0DJJHYdnOLxtbynKjkF6hGGCFQdoNRPjgJrWbZeM2ufwYeuoEuPR541WWXVIMmtI0/Rbyhy1kOZkAmrlBPYp09womv2zF45gHbbmKGfiQvDiLE8@@OEvS9FFeSKPJVlc0tymuGtTEnZtnOAKFs6hoYOxpZOziMEbVDzzW6b46y2@O7MET/hLPuzHaYmu6YfFfnvR5OGMR/C5KOtu4GlaumRUQOFQAiWhNGLEYMJNf/jKirzNZWd5eX@1cxaOZVB5een6DZdhnyxfptQiLPDEMD4bsyZWbi/1s64qZzfT6N6patpraN5WTy5OTr4aj2IUSjewdv5b1NQi6wTbp99Bng6XnPOzTnkhkJSlFkiv6441k8s2bNyDy4lMuakU/iFaJldVopaxsCIducWNjJbGeXUmcPolWIS9Q3JiSTsfOmGUl2YXVcxsN@DltuglJifCHbW9jemCAfybcusMmGYc7Zqs1KBkj7m5FBvg58ETcZ9999eoVGl7Rw96divgRDlGAi@SqRiZCmUyn0n/xJ0u3iZuT6tZffL@bNJfwc4yfH90@Q/OZnvlsaemz3d21tQQgjptPvnvy9c7Oztp@InNSzmyvqamlrT//s6WldHornVyquK5eiZYvv5LTqTVZ@4vfi1ZPTr7julh3@KwyHYz4zsJPZ5kMu2Tv4LlsMvwn87tGyGygudZ8hx0kCMsFYjbRaGY1evY6ivXzLqLremREf1Uq2hLTi9sb/@0nx99EvEgxnXzVh68X@Sayno1wIxjAturbriLFyBYGW7@NjJKFQgGMG//t30P84hcAB31GW/AqZnxY66NIUS1QlPeR4joY9HQa0v1/vvc9KVIcQiaKxcMDli6mVwSZ6NnH@mMy2V4bBIyLiJ5dO35CVst8cpzOpLfQbJt4g0wbhqPIZHQ9fcFE5emiCrG4Or65A2uDGevUiTA/6LjOmU9RTFACEAjRCDcLByIb7oDeE@FeXRjGykZ8Lf3Ezr8KPROWf4jnFK/qWl968mY/mdwqQk@PTy735KIqmlmSbWRlx3mCk395diRc8/gaOqrqQHD4XZCjio9AYCRbSFQ5kvxW5vuwsY2FnSIClyxoUL9CuBI@f/l//eVP//In9PdT@v1nKeJvxFHLV5Wi/wAFycW@fHMhrPYz9ow/tg3/8POt6IIOYLLF3GQkeIpFfNG/sJGJvlNuwqcYWCjEOMrccMznWJSuFPmQTLIc1tJVsRguDzzJwErF4Dknw7NQ6cblE@UB1ri9vQR/9A9PYMX3ErkIZwpy91lixQXP4j5AipQj5UplOGQTQBZCxOdUQ6rThK0a7lWupIgKjCoePwUqZYK44bmI3/O8gJ@mVYUtqY2hRqTI3/tTlFjkBp5KXL29LWuv4/m8@AcBLx/Y8OEmyFrlVlW3Xhfj8TJlsVwUed1So2tOdN15wipFXgB6a9XXWwA@vlXeKjh79NOqiC@18rpY3pqEQWAqxSdP4ojaJwCguFxhMLSA2rjdui3elrdub7e24H@L3rfiC663W3f@6TN@5oQZ@1ew/i/KyeJFUrTKYgXsGhA1uGjJC6Ru@EK4clmK3CDlsHKF9NsV1LK@nqmojFrICnCvZE5fSa8mM8PP1ktpYAIuBk/LcnIFDe@xuwSBZ1OK4NBhk48gNsnhzcdv/w/8XXz89t@CFbKGFwmSb@0b/Dt6h3/fePh3Xse/02/w7/wd/p16@Peshn8nLv5JkQJjILEtb6c6qauUfqlfgsFiKRCY26m23oDOhqVMlhqlRizVdfQGmEz4S4HJSjVZqsVSdsrWdfAEg8dSHpqa8GnBXxOg9OHPSqUQeOqKQSod7MJILzR931dZ7EIqs@gbE8QsTddS2rpVrWTWe9@Uo5V8JHlxkeSyJ0uv5UkP@O0tY9Vq6fl@tZpE4r945hyP/4@Pu2Hrwv/usfPs2Ok68H98fPzsAhhYMf4krj6Bp1CMb4nPdqSY377IqUi4PglHklvbF8VVFc3rcaDKNLrFP/EZQ4RvcelCgrH5q1fXeepn89dX@es8GQIrN1RFABGMGyBWXvTP4ALxLl4lqUe9hueK4JINjdfg6Zu4Ifnq@gIlSBgvBP@AjrD17@Hf@v/X/7MXTClXYtAIbm63FHpi@BeL3dze3Ip3MaYowqJswR86gB2j3NwW0UiBbsBUVmKV2O0td4O3EtviAIuYxlaRIo8DAqeIBGlSuvyl/P1@MW3@XERBTIKRtCKWAS8uhqlULF8Dl2AtwHhPK0qxPO21Wa7hKiCMHvUYhcis5fP6Cjen19L5/JqwbGTz@awwLyvK5t2nmNrW19dz6bW1WCyfT4mwME7M@0YAYbpGPY@NPB@JYWZ5y1dSOBtJN4BE5Zz8@LEi7ozZ7vVijx/rm6n37wOnarVh9atVdF99/16uyrgtp7CZAXsq@/49MJ1ozOkrzx2@IKyoOvssXaQUNp0@lGoDvJmeTI/TbBuu4Xl95Z3VS8i479OVY6S1O5Vy@hfRX/z4@9@/iBZwowa5rukIAFNhma2t9bVicX0NzOtZKLi8zHf@KK34ph67XU7KvLhMXo5GhJee3YiR620U/Vlki20XoaG6@LCb2wjVH1vLxJTayIzdgIvvpm9ucke2tq5k45vir7AUY8UVJv7K5fJqfG1lY@VJBcWbOw8y1fyNUYgmk9Hbwo2Rw1mr23xd3A6BJ7KMx49XNwGZ2VT@QqpW93fOd6p4sSSuyUPvx9CROLSE6629frRMU4yZzUoZC1a5iEZz@SdU7Xo2wyLRvAinRoHbs@wmlT/iupLVxKOZQ4I69VuJ9Ji@sQrdKvSqUo@2R22kWANXmPvMaTaXwBHqjtVwM4Brdjr@jRrXTr/TuLYa5pIUOTna2SudJ9Jb0EmnD3b2EumzF7sRHa2ZsR29WWQVHU5LO/vHLyDGyVFp56z0@eHL0osTcHelt@8M0zTMgWleVweD62/w1gWzavbAdfxUzbrlGm/fGj16YJTCmfPHn//w48//p4@/@@OPv/vDj7/70198@9Mfwu8P4Pdj/v3xv9vM4PsX3/6z3//4O78Ljv8Zfv8Jfn/yi29/63v8R/Y/hd9/Cbn9qfiFwvGfBLB@/Rff/uT3fvHtb/wMfv9S/H529/ebfzL799MfzP9hvJ/8/uIwP/738PtDDssP@@Pf4W74vRP@d3i43/jZx3/xH/j/n4s/NP7ux3/xp/gSln/6sz//Lx@//x/T6eyf/5uPP/zxxx/85OMPvv/xBz/6@IN/nP74W/9GT4Vfv//xp3/03//4D//7H/8v9P8H9P7Dh/x//Nk//av/86/@77/6Y/H7E/j9BzD9yV/9R6DUv/mjn@P/T/7ob/7Tz/H/f/9Xf/NH/@vf/Pq/JsNvc8P/@y//HX//9fd/@Nc/@Od//f1v57x/uPD97QPcv/0HcHl4Ph8C5yHl@lSXb3@l/PxdsDFOBWiAbrdgaZBhd0cmzVZ8NsxJn7FIcQUfYMnlbDobXwHxc2VzE/hyhdy3MAiToJ3@9J98/K1fA/L/FwAMbP8z2OCfW8DrR2RhX3014cniNAOixr/6Cj3FkPGrcKgfgcP7JAjjqSfvIcRX5M0fFgSDdP83CgbhmAjmh5vMAIXBLZ7c/Rff/vPfI48gLjr/2gTIlO8cDr2Mwd/7Rf0RtvtxacKhf4Ss4@PPv/fx9/7xx5//9sef/zp2DeraZmInAT374kleCJh5QDgMuP6QcBBQxyEjDPGXpDQYlrZwYlLS42/eQO6XwAQjrhUpswo2SS@SWUczRIyDjYAMh3F8w7@0tsnQAi5DcoUvi4PXbhxvPY9LwwL4UVC8Lp2hsZgFpyFOLRQALkbicRLVLIxl2HCXoEDMQvyUVVcKQx4xjg5FgoBkI6HTqayn5Xi2sA8JFob7DGEh8Lj0Br5vCsVsYVhEcB8oCwAjvgtJQii8jT0@LH4Ae4FgQnhpuP8BspItxOPFLLgUsJBxSi1RpTT1DBWOyh5nVG50Zwy3Wm4/gSYj61mZT30AKpkIje/4ODQGhODgfxFfEcWhf99IvxWMD/U0JPxwN@6/jc4UXwQAuKqKO/Tgp6qYmyfgPeSg4pQsfOIcAmAuTkKUDxIcSF6JS3Gq3zhZIH3Iw6c9W8gqEBwWZ3l5GUxbRXlVrh7DEBLGav3LnOsZfVxBJDkyx@T1TRmdcbsT38i5fEJjzZX9FXjr8F9aos3LVJb8irQcxVmLKM8apKXGV501J8KL4ZeRbCtUhDgFZJ@BD/6ePAEz4Ii@YzecaKD/uPQ6IrEI1T00lgR/w0crkHuoKZHD64IUH9tpNpvH0LSElkiIr0ZfctCEQSNf8dWWSWBkfNhD69RMX19jMUmhe8ViWEN1k4Qx6Znb2nWGMORIyHJCX8e1p5iYpjnPpbG1SqVcCt5fO7lc4YO@tiHBl@wDvN9M3LQFdIO3vGtbW1j/xRuV5pLQCCLrulQsimV3pkvFs9I5BD8/Zno6pTEYrtysbaTXMmuZ9Or6emYjra@tb66tZ7KrwFnXU5l0Wt9cW9vMbm7cBth6AswpkVupZbaK/@jO8z/8o1nPbFd8pOJXbKjR/PmtVOwU@PbPZVyCly9Scp4mtgiXy@VUAv/Sq6vwhnwm9MxGZWmpc6NisS9oz@ENbnKArEo3KnZ8j@Bh0iOJPQIneCANXIRkYtvI4XFebBHAa0r5NgFZzwAhQz1cACVzcFCjNzc3oZ8UWfrudz1WLMKwQz08kCLQBtvMXxRXrYbW1uh20cagb5Jvi7H9w5eHZ4fHz7X9wzMYB3yN55E0KXJ7e9sMlnLIarLj42MJmR@M71Z1jH9bZ4PBgHxrYL8dGlIv/OQDk5ROq@lVdVVX9VX8v8eQxv@Hh0/DfxrfEGs1LfFziR08vuNPm21KW1zLRtG/O16rOY2RZuFVOHhGreCNeiZd50Fn9s65MvulQjS4nDW6nc5s5oLovuEZVMV2ej0NDWNjS6i@Km653qhjFjGJm4bl9jrGKGfDaPsW94/mjCbk76bO913k5HQmK98@6ZoNy2AQHwdqOIZWunifBO4uzqUuUrGbmVHXU/LtLSRLyUlbQndGkZbDy9BGKnjNXrmy5WvVKEofPnwY0g6U3KHtia0o6bUsujMJGcNj6HEf69yYWR8bU2g8Rw0oz4FIoWXb7Ah3lHsOO3f4zuVdsz4nxF7boFsH9/oODGh/9TC7hn3JvfYtrooh8HpqoC5mt2t57TkhXvS6eCTT7P@DQSh1a5BBJAseYBde/Y7jzAqwwV6czCnls0BzEu5aIdVJEPz08POn56HveWln76m0znaPn@9PfTIiUIYdlQ7OA@sG9/WjZgIQX5eOjqat4gPdRp5mMJZYZsM36CxiyImqXK7kOzfebTbfN4feRmozs60/fqyfHAEWl5OMXdgDnC1I5XKk8uHlMmtCgQq7EF9fZ2tsvVgqZleBkC9zH9StjqlVodA1IG5oeoDok74LJFEaDtgLwzOa1JLT13lzKeD5y9Iz3DO7qfMDYJYr0TlMvN4Or7L0JFTZ0MAr7HGqq4Z3yQ96bK4jfNAJjdD@29BJXjt@AKlmGAx@n/pA/PDUB@BvoYPH0yC3Oz6dGcFxk4bVZClJ4/jZzGaym6vpbCK7mV3L6OuZTEJPJ/SN7MYmdE8pPauvZzObeiK7trm6Bn0o@GY2N6QIdCtWM5kEQUWXZfjmAKxdxxtZtvBqG0drF6UIZ4XsnWLEgAIC@4DJJsSR8W5A16NjAStWQU6v4ZmdVahsWTZYnUUODvZSBweyvIsWXP/YS8lyAy2ZbCq1sSvLJvnsQT@flmWHxwEvCOZxSyq1uyfLAw4A9TvJchstpXUcRcmyhZa9nYMDTOctWtIYH4Jdch9u6fiWDQhmo2V1lYZhsvxNAA7C7fCE1iinJbRgmuhzwH32wE@WP/fzk0oBhFMejkN46pd1Z0eWD7llZwd9vqCCZ3hWv0TLDj2y3AcLEKEst8DQwh5BlmtgRFKU5TqY6iMD3PD2G9T5Y3uGLI84ghBFsjyk0Eb9UobBgnDHZJ4@fWq0vYbZ4s@oz791yBr4WMNB6aD2@ee1VqvWH@2UPj9Fny@@eGq8HQ36tVZNRKtV4XEgDvhcdkfTD@TxsFo1OjN9vgQfe8qnOqqamLeq8Q3kSTwtTKRb/QJ8vgCfGZO0Qw4Nni4EreGz24XvrlEjH/8hH/oOazU5j4SKvT1OqmKbubSBFyS6Rr3v5NE@LCyxqBJNjMrrqUqe3FlXYbGbVP4W/ZsK3bCKgjbyoNjNqDwspCowjNxIi9NFinwxTGcsObHU3dY3M7klY1tPr8WHOVTh7TSjLKrq24r@eOWd8jy2nV5dy8kX29uqXNYr22k9m1vfeL0ykOVYDt/bqxu5dyCNR0HkxlesvFHZ3siEomxsxI1kOrexEcvfAkI86JRqA8@sVhXl2jQuYyyGOca@XondUHHZiIpq5ZvKMDEs8GyxEYvlhwU9z9VPsNQUNKYoDVSANMDrDAXQFgOQw@1UDie3FVnfzMqQiWRSicWQMyEvge@bV/7aW/AJGSaM/NFYTuW3oerZ9ZiGp1WqTrNKN8KxN@GQOKaQXuHRMjpW7u8ApWGgm5POcQiCnQHJVlYNL2AmlQwwGOdquxifl9I3NiWpKCTwE34XVV5YP3@6p4FQLmyoTEk7GNiIBQ3vi/YmfLiiH9/pHDpG7amJ@zrrvtseP/CtlYYw4sJDLb7HkThspAklCNr50/yNWsXJ8e@cX56ff1e9DYM9g9EIzwgejMmTugk8Yo6qp6wGMwpFMBkNhfLIjNg14aJaLBaqha7Z7XkjGKfyFX4ouR/7@aDLdhkPi8fV/MM61cIuICmVt1H7oonWZTaMDKViA5VL7RZ2bwY5lClv82bB7PedvhzBM37bdmFgu0bTPDH7eLzs8BilABMPctXbby5KGHIPquTmVi32mT0uxaHLMRmcFqIs3WCWhEe1kLrNT@RbMdRiLTbhpoSsX3INuGMHxKDyHR81N7TDGtdwbvPNgvI6lv8GbP1lpjS0XWjo22v5hrLLqiyGjtDn4ivN1tfydGOBgtCAL1AamD8jVih@CYTHgV/mcpA7QR2XhR6MwZZpT7fSZD1LVE6zYDUonHGbbxXK6PYeX1uqLFdUtfy@AsPnvFQEhpMfRYyCO6jxe0ZTNRg5r@eH4KZvrOXbrFaovR7m@5QOy3eAGsQYlu8jN3BPMaAd4Lx7r3z8te/FttRMgbvlCdb7DkgXVa1aGI6rfLVQTsMIN72@hiPe9VX46TDyTeMuyUQ6tZlI6yBkgPAB8eG3AfY1@EEYkEHSOo6LlY4C41g5kRqmND2hm3pCSb2xGm9iiUvFFxRjCc8p2VCf4IDVCpRMVvgasXh6paM0HGZsqUTYwADzVEgj0QZEJtoI5tQ0Ojx4TGWrK0pnWSGEnw96pXIllysNe98BDqYq6jfb6/GNVPwdnthSlmIF1/yGMIzcklDQWwI6E2N95g665RRbglJDu1RvodrBUd9I58qDZVZWdShg6n1rSy7KFaiuWybBX3jREOSwPLj5fJFLbmPZa@zWQ6G7Y0LN6pvpvAgi9QSnVmQF76Xn27CVaHQjHY3Gonmc5FoCd8HpiSVHoZOIPta3ZZD95Jy8mQb/MX@/kwM@YF6H4f2thCNXBkPnyI10e3O7Fd4r9iUbjYy46lsfM9aKL0ssSbs5tGqELZFJ1Yo0FblT2Gmd7uRF6J09KZKjbYzjjWbsQhxbZ2py6VP3kMS3iq/59wL3S0GyEqlSK7OKmABIr0KhGyE7FNC9kThW@T6i5Fa8yJIXkiwT4@Lr0NlMjOeVfYhQI2d7N03BcXPPcPAMPCfHG3W5Evvw3OrcZFdVPgBXWOQDiyc12gpXTX6IQM94S7j29z1@@SadAezbju8AQ20PWDt0pJmMjJNu5hvWO9t8vfE6@/rZi@MXxwfsSSqXzWWnZt0vniQSelSPbrEnIM9bpyUYt71nTkb/YH/BN4dG8pFcL7q6Fl2djlqIDAtr/kYDRS8WVX0rzbaBVlkOmG9TX1dT74uc8IrksZ4Gn4@/9rO14VYW7GmQm3OA00w8XSzqK@lYpPfx23@LxxtvSi93jlgUlU387Z/9Xnrjb//sX9GqdvQ2j27p1Y0IhESjvr4Rubnp3dzcwsP9MpFKhOdpbSMGZr7jQo8Uk8JZ39BjEVflNshuJuK@F9pnlHQqC357x9wmrwM2I5sRKZJ99uY9Y1swqC42Wi0rTaZk8s4yxjKOSOGffcBpyw/q0ptCcTkJBIBzsJsYwZ9mWykWiyu4PsKixTge1U1naJmmfJuvAFLxwZHaik1/pruCf2h/zR1WXBfsvjdYcYp8y2SZos5gdJdMfvy130qn1//2z37zIva@@r76XeC1m5ub63o68kvIx4Lzc/7wjCZ58CQcGoJhHZtzJaJWl6UIzXoxHt4f5OGwDk@Pc907aJOuUM4gFFcBjwbI1AoFW8FTQAmSrunIcCwvSYEIStJzv1VPEAy2gvpnoe1IN9Ij9IJuihWAN0mPxqDAoYtKe@pVtzPo90gOVCieXkmwxxAFUniEah6W6PSSYHCqnmfJlbtReZa5xhcSVVjXdF3U9AT8V3oEUY6ASukiG9Yz8AQchrRsYKgaBqF8kkejDGlXIO0Oj1AlV4VKzwMkGM8dj2SDdC09wuM8JH5D78usLQiQZzHpESAAyqAIwFaFbbHVGLux4vH8WDHULe5JQ60Ahn@@RsJoCK2Bh8r8yHkMZ3HlD4M@KkRioobrZtjRB8Jh8NWTAgwMMDrZUJKhI3QPBgWw6Ci1QkVjjx@Pc1UA@SbGqEQIH/VioTKrsRafOwkAMH9M9VkjJyeYHY9jZT@aJDvAeJyyC1SnkmEcqIkHndB6K0nw/2CiRYqcqiryyGMBRH3xVlEHlEFkRDuvwzpq9tLTGzEWZL4Oea9TpkhBSDBQvBh@ppGenjrP4q30y4ivwFHCC6dDoxpBt9MHrBjwpQFe6YOnxzkzEEen@GUPyJwOPT92EAuKYnUodNPqwwiBVoJ8VSPKqh7DaM3AhfJBe9HSawy3iWVi@KFYGBoVUhio3EGks0TT2KQVy@05NmmDoJO1uJmOdHS5Etd9wbM9sK8N0uvEU6G9Z6EccWVZSPmky8nmCqtcHhdXnWp9GOv6uEkws6WR2pP0JlO4AjY8dm8H4GIUiTIMo0IDcVzrmF3I0plpMtRI4OaSyZbltQc1UkHwzAK6ah9Y0G3YblJcHpS8ti6t5DkqoFOdJkik4shbhL00OlagDUic8ydlXh3r0uSDVWXizKLL0usJEPcSgNnxDxCbw0lYPJeYAu8EDwW/DfhscGM2EYq7pIxid7@r@pJSjZFYQIpa@nhB0JVhh/BLz3tJDDHdkesfSKYTcmDXApYLLZOfSorisaTguJwkTk4X6FSvhrPjPQXEKf8cHRpBxDSvIISqS9jHANOs@wf8sBVDaR9RB0BtD1oWauzw@jk8@VpAXVZKHZqeYPA2@4ytpunadX4WXBzdBhhY9YVJ6OAHUbEcrteAitH4DAPwFWid3Qb4RVCBDSc/jO9TN5pJe82YvNmSAIedDqVVYLxZ@JZMyIKtg@sig6Ivgec65HBGTpYUOQ5g43JM5qCD@NPRObVLxEty7C6kBEMIAtUABUWFXcPluiiFuo3r62uNNL4M@pZmuqgk1MWLz5K9lgXSqJP0zG5P3O9g4eU84uKxsUnlSoLxnrztIV1Pt/l4xL@S1MQzqN8MrL6pRJtuFPvAK@CVvVaXjtPjQXeX6ObAIqW5dYUWJ11BZulK4sYnsxySmZqN3iIQxhDMMDFK1BMALFGrXyaa14288LiidgfAobJM3xGVsfV9S9f1TVavGYRwPNrW6ttrncu603FQ9JD5TOo4aV5CP@TItwp7zxpCJNu8Zjv9vjFSyD@GoZFOlRFJN2wEvTv5gBF6E3bDdRZZw/KoMhF9GESHvssfe7A@HqaXbhYD5aqi0H/I/YfgP@T@w3GifrLlYYVLXuh0i8VB4kbdOH5IBDPyw9xyTVdjH4IMcjHTOQgMOZpwu4VfvUCxfXxzG9RjwScMoAlSMKegZrvyRcV2zeuVSjzZApqWCRFQ4wC6XCGcXjcCM2K/c9XpOe6Ek42qY6DzEflGp3pbUAOnFSxjUEFEGBxfFmoYaXU1PnXC@31RYICA4hZ4ogSw4ylWLB/o9iRPIJyyPMYxz1hZZKZCQpbwEm4gFXHUc8SGAVVCgNA9KBJkE3yY33KECmjBBF718bZMP6xKdxSQktJoJQqYnGoqnKXkqZJCuVJVP5uAdpRKC9NF8f2hKspTXqFi3or6D2d/6ZOz34R2MTv3RLC8X8hL4aZiDlEhoymaC2GVFQuheoUcJFeMjtmHDqrExVDRKUMyK0l/NMHTwSJwRaJKqPLrMV4/dGJAtuVcQAqjQgGKOCrwZsnbhY9SjvAgmiuijXxCEPE5AwEYqZnRTBFtGI42LBQ442DDOdGuQ5kcUiaHPAoPPZyTyYqIBoOkQFUlVk8FNZSBQCUDPJ33lqiNU2aucYUqV9lb1CgCgyc/zTHPISoQNISSNNJZvTIz9XIo0yGmNQUACfEOgAa/cSInTTM8XQ1sAY/iqPR5FLcJMuC8AgiMWHCea41SAiKjoS7I9XKc@gFou3K8LMk6bg6ivxT/yQnf0f/pdx1TkyH1ScdUYurvH8SxgpgNNdCQkKGn1pAh44Blh5RogFhy7TBlhvAM7kn/StFkrePUkl0DN1Lg3cPBRaMxfzxAavKe9BzP8Jy1tRwfBFlEXy9EcBbS9s7HAFbLdmCoEdZKZ3EtenYUlQXWnZZtuWYCrzblIrhJy/1cObcUlnuF0XElScz68WEpguYEhKJrtYrX4lSrimt2mrFcoPIRrRrSYTQq4XgWTKH4wIcE0OOe4uC9zl7sfpioslFEO7fql8pxT3hGIZEdBsyqDvI8@LZBVGGuMx4Jki41FI1rnkKqydtO12mBeId6EjH2FPjDMWzMkNHrUV4SzMAhai6k2JKag1JPGDER9ctPjsq@TCtGLIifngQwgYwE60/jGDHbn5FcdW5yPJqf3tmn5/csnN@zxfmlUfV0nvlQu8A9Py3pVWUMAQKOs7F6fzYSQi3xnexMZCVwRgGKR3hwFhu0UamBOd2BoDsiuNYE@kgENpeUpYiMv5yH/8UV6EcvPbT6DLwl7GwE/KaL@@EUUs7v@quACgQ/jCHvuZtcQNr7D0wLwoIcwQ5QVgB5lRiXjZp4oGH2YBjtysGShwB8D83jPqQ7dE@bkwrcc0ae@lcJdpmeX0X71YbZMUZmQxEhEyG4folPYWRG/OphBUdGR0zP4YM6BTqpWFiNLyKdB8rNIRkjcRVS4nwnDA9iBdRDM9@Uw8P5@EP/O6wZp@wKfPYZBP5oNEL6vkk9e2/UG3ENhh1@hYXgo7z/4TWJ5ybvRwjgQexgSIyTjS1in6dKUKQH9AhBWG2yyKSryO@2nG7vbh1@GoruLylUbihSwa/lCR3L82rcWlTjIarwaZKv5zyMJO8jugfTXIjUOLAxC9v7tC7kDmTc@lCvK2GI3GVhjTn2HZ6AbjTvZs/pVaozGGoQkzidZ9G4muSLmIRD4EP44gTSS/giwJbpVTlB@WXDOSpx2Qkjn67RC0ktwgWkcYASwqKvSZ@yEQol@WYIfnMbpFmfm2b9Tpr1iTSDFjCZZCiQVJ9IUtQCVs@iKuiYTW8Od0YvHCTDZxHbhsd2jD5OS9xErWjOSrDoVTQHDDlqRnMlBZhytBHN7ZPBjebOyHAZzX0JhnHbir6P5vxmgQH6YCXDE3QXLBzt9WhuT4ndSh5eduCnq0VzQZ1CmG1uJYwAKrDcIDXikpntiGJ6fRM6NhIqEwwpxk3gOIkmXBL0S8E/12rOb98AT5yzXKHALM70iU4j1GPwdKDb8PVdzmjJOdGbl44PaOvQWG08@MdhMBeOQ@BBDI9EJ5kRzxj60goFfCGDyDdzs3PE9Mm7BR6QHZE6UChV8mT6hD2N5IGGQv5lCFyJTaqsF/H9@poEwSvwYfnEyPPyeSc7fnKUI1xjjc3IFiL1TXRBobCup@5j4LUfriGau54MhLfq@UF4LRHYEE8HGY4W2zCxntObJBLyxV19VjgOzb7xRonUOxWNuIJomXO8yVmUDBlDuPHHFhUnFA@zNsGC0LOcqvBWFvQLxIvRa8zrQpIqb3yQhRDPgRZu1i9NJNt9YaRwnN0kqK@Y1w35cXmSxLkm2SRE1lABxMDweOrB4LWEaiE@bfjqxxzipIqCAEIxg1Q4f3U@QX53uPzuC9Q@EqYSmCVYz@5K74rXC3vZqZx3xsnerUD0TLD92EzhKEhhjHIYHYQk80W0dkfExy0cXMjniQbQp6R9H23BmOAevE2PLTgslBL6V5OOl2lwvEzPR9RdiaRzpflCi4YpCTi84EFOx0VbnFde8FlVjD40kW10PrmC@5MVHK48hEcF6E@hnLdyPM6Ha1vjtk3KRNEFWaqeY5yR0/JnUM1jR2D3tBQbLMOCw3H1dP/4@dHX0OlubGzERB89GucPWy1Oqgb9OIdMe4@D/mDGsCWdQGXauHiN8@50S@XShS3f4SWcWYMwgJeI@OQn2nhM8LIQP59quxCPhw1hVMC6HDcDY4IroahjYJdtCbx6gBDTU1YMAcQXbwHfCRqtxXBOFqgD7yOrVqn7qlZxM1K1KnoxrBp/hTv2y8hScuD26XpArur3WpLo8C3bP2avnu6cs/OnJXbwYu9L9vXxC/Zq5/k5Hl49ebF7dLjH4Fd6flZi4xkFfPD6AxxQAl73zbrZrQHLTqdSa4wg7zm9Eec7yl6Mu58ZXfbUqZu4HrXlGt0nbW7RbNMr8lglGI6OxE3XPTwz5Xn86rA6gCPhpkFH1HD/PoOwNRjTdnHM23UaVtOCsBKOfXuW6fonqFjHghoEfusfcExwIQmvYqCtQHQNF92ghldwQXhcpAEwhju@8s1yeQSzoTGBuOD5ZAyel06fnbGd5/ts7/j5/uH54fHzM3ZwfArWk68Pn38O@Dw8Oz893H2BXhTw2fH@4cHh3g458AykNIbHk@lOtUVZ0DA4YaV@iUvcdN1nYAvPOkMwkODZtUGH9VwWHdjIfSyjY70zG9G8hJe08AOCtCbAgivSmPkNLmX6a760n0B@4dI1I8sptkWpQWMpQnvLi@YK3R4qfMaFh@6I4XUzZp5ODStkHl9jQ5tyGpbJ5D3cc4Jz3/xwMbVlHzQktASwEZS/AaXASHt6NJrYIpBFSK3ecVAFFk@NbwoUFoz6xN86kpcIY2LvCwLFQwGHNs4H6fnAAegeHNIiWa/PA7DVwIEHYGvcAUXRQ9wLwjIixMA7HiB7Zuvc4W23d0Drv2wjcNg1aBSbFXni9UZVarDxNcJWt9ch/fd8loeutTHcumVRFJfCo/74Tse/W65mAskDTxQ3AeFeNQgpA7Np4lKD2MZmD6hhgy9QA@77MZqey5RCTGPnuNnHtC1@sUCrY9h8S9N4Kw7RHsui6oiC2G1tBRr7G/wObyJAvEVjMh9BvH0hFZoPjQcxd@@kaIg9j3Tri7@l7L4M7N7JwK8CBgCpEyOdOvVUdFYTwThNQcqK6wBF4rzth3B4IOfGoG5ORPBv/ntrvXsXE0hOTIyT/H2HlDuoIrwkMcHXLJtOH9o4sdUuHlpBLlhvOz3P4nWoTJZgfG8ThMaODVJ7UyhOpEZ3NU6laDt2KNEaUPGcVGtAlA9JlSieL5IH7Mtv68HFUbSPDrNj1JwrM7R2lsBFpGsTp19AEOaX3mFvQ5eYCvlTGvOOD3QRYbZQ3N@9UD@8SaDae84W@FVP/iZCfnFhF9OC5kHrfLQBsY9yl2hp/t0J7qCGscWeOsEtsZX7wGAc2LZgXPekmg/8@Pbhu@54fmTanRzfvy/wWCpyJs6RB25bGXO3BCv7SSYoToWJvR4h3gmZBV6v@C4Jghnw6yd4UgRrIQ8YsZGP0JWjk3cWCBbil642aAJnEbcSieoO4MdYkbZO@IIkPUq4PpKvld1CvBhLjneOsBA6FZ9FJ3zIeGnReP8J9Vd3wO0vBgf8@@Hgsgtzx7uHT4K2vxDaJ@VNjc@HxbulEKyHg/2wACzv3H4lsFD2xHzAvJO8Cy2g9IA4E8uRYHfs4hTf3Kk7ansABvtenEEJgIZSG9i0RO3rqVR4hFgYzFggOjvfL52eMpmPTyAu8D0cMjQEG0TYS/xKB7571rKJ2WmB0BQMlgPhyXeZ2LoWHPlY0JhnIm8OqxAySELgI2AWkxcoEtcTPQuJELSbnhiij7nJ3N34PMgtC8C3qJgUmFdkLIYFBZRmFjPCOx/LDW/qFnhLcNk4vCefdkzzvhuvQuqPwoDCm3@MFp4UmV1/r7h8nPPT4QKW@c2ACtwASRpvA9XYGSTcg4CaNlmDC6rFr1LcNM8F7IiPO9zhlZqUsP/uBEWExIVwLguH2LoQjkXWuHy87Is5tPMQuwEDt3QKT75DGTx8Fk8uW@EKjY07PWWyCwIhEy/peRKmCoheuc0H93oq436yEAjk4ba2TLkp@7ms4OysgJ2fH@gz3Nu8Ps0eppMCbrswKfXvJyneS0yk5ON8ZmF8T4C8nsms3gd7uhR@dPXvCpv3IdP80@v2YHw/BumOXJreB8o9fJ7w/ccEsAB1fKu832CmIoKoM6NPmSg7dUbh/EFe@LwQZAZVv9bbeCXRZKoxNpzK22zovEcKQ6cgd8oQasJBQXmruYP928XJIUO@N72lT0@PNzYMhHsEb38ZHK4LKU0JOeEx0Uk3s9@3KRg/ltR18PgYnUZaeGaODs3xDa28MOhJy2zhAjTFISO@rTbhTzFQIjSrqOEVZjipl5@e1VP1fLiEB4dHJbZCOsmaE1OQcl@OhVjOkmUvygCxXpqOwF6DjuJ95ubgB3lI@CABTXQoTyHcxO7NG2EEhOUy6dQX2z4FS9WnK73p1g0bNXgkZLr99zFEpMnX0vFBbNaEeio/ER8y5/ZsBWIlZFWTKSq44TwuQpoEwWsT3UP9lIQ65cUGyQUXnhpJPZta35SodHbCS3TLm5XESr0gM@hzDbvrDvrXjcuW075qsg7rva0N66N33zCWWWN4xDf9mGtf1NcLeLpVYXhHU5ZtpohgRQa3SZPkhcwYqTLBs9pRNh5@55dQMSA8NFbO4QmIKSplK12fCvGknFfoltcrBbuQynfLdiWPZ/W8eMGL63EFHR5D5wmshS/Il70KdqW/DM@2mvYV6w9qIxglBWc/GJ39wP4dZ7jEnm2aL6dtxtIj3KyGZ0g027xWgsuckTIllH@kR3SIR8fT3jRdjLMtDQtyANhPgLDqDuk9ikmPUtqg5znkIxJSkYTYe@u99Mg/dZSiCQMIUrYqfna2CM44jILrPtx1xHdDqzqXxnQ86hgLgShjTOJ28oUs4xFAzKg4elWuSK5mGvU2ZgKv7XtP0djWFr/P@xa8aZIOd2oYfTr4kKqgEdc34NOjxQRMggRzl45vSFB8tOto4C40BeXReRfa6C6RIIg@uI2b3dBxJIq/BQjgiH/ERSpNzGAKwQrkRH7Uj@YOUHnc5LgeVxHwFCSvlEdYWITN0yuMgdOOb8IRJivQBO6PrhGdHFfwiBKoOtnuFCMIH@PBCSW0DC1sLuKSqpS8ivjpjKMpoWiqH80PHELFo3uxgRNZMPp5ZkLzGbE9s9OBTHNcPBqjA410HFekHw/Sd8uYZiXIPPdX7/irE/4a9@eZGofSoP8eB8qFA8mRm3G4WyaPgyXupFVgJJtoUNN1DSSOcdj8orCu5jlVaxy4GFQlp8rAY2vCQw35vJ5R@9xnaSJOQOCBf5n7C/pOi5oPcjkR9slk@viVRAWZtDdWbCWZolLNtjrbvHMKfJDMZIYXxPPoWN9EdrxRiiOTgp2AgIbT@NRsi4UxlLjucxxqM3Jx64msCWFiW5nOBj90eKdhzWgjISxRmnFC3JDOF0I65L0UAkEwkdCY33KLfuSRiDwKgcVQS36y/NDinQYORZtu4gU8xvgeX35jn8ycHy4y2/MRz/mQF54fRp5EEDHdJXk2mia5CR774I6iUAt6kXHao2mIs5nE89Akb5CmyY9MN3GWeyngE2FG4XOKO3gPfASmxwF0n3znVSF63kq/TK5InxsgQvc65pDt4CjCoNNU0sR5dM90PRf1G6H@Shie93odXFQkwe6aTjwL3RzpDK6mjCGGltE06RA37vDwCTSJ8@MQSWPHCPka93@MPdxBq8Vvg2eoyghYK06oWJ4m7dgjPl8BbWY1zU@Fm2zg8kVRGMy3wpngNcdbD91gj3ekaxLIYi5IORIvapO3bzFdjsdCUNkWdGk5SfrOwKpf7n2Oy7UbempVD6HsSqz2prTVtfFBKUCS75FOgbia0dckKbT0W@dLvyoCTLAj7OhfAm2aV3hlrbQDPQYFdEE4dc3@ldnQJOnUDNZ4ES6SMi484rFpZ9Cv87kbkK3wqls87esm@GoXUBh@sX/mq8F1WgpLSLgmNV5MxjvrrQYi0D9Q0nRw8ZfWI/BUP8cHRuqaHiBlJcYms0RLyyIvJLt0cZ4JsGGIW@vF0kOABtvxrDrUDE1USR0AxVc5xonxi7lDOYH06h0DD/lqszKAp1/GGPAz4K8ULcqDJNbEPykPTBTMX0I3/JpJAvdzqK1Aczf7FnDfMYKpVihaKO9QwedPD8/Y2fHB@aud0xID88np8cvD/dI@2/2alrBxHZwUvLKnx0fAXYLFcr4ofgwO8s4ZxJTJQ9p5/jUrfXVyWjo7Y8en7PDZydEhQAPwpzvPzw9LZwl2@Hzv6MU@La4DBPb8@JwdHT47PIdg58cJStWPJo3jseMD9qx0uvcUrDu7h0eH519TigeH588xMVy032EnO6fnh3svjnZO2cmL05PjsxLDgkn7h2d7RzuHz0r7GqQPabLSy9Lzc3b2dOfoaKqgx6@el04Z7QEIlXK3BLnc2YWhKqZE5dw/PC3tnWOBxqY9QB5k8CjBzk5Ke4doKH1VguLsnH6dEEDPSt95AYHAk@3vPNv5HAonKfdgBepl78Vp6RlmGjBx9mL37Pzw/MV5iX1@fLxPuD4rnb483Cud5Zl0dHxGCHtxVkowvD2IkgYYgC3wB/Pui7NDwtvh83PoM16c4HaGGFTyK0AM5HIHou4TgnGXA5YWkHR8@jVCRTxQBSTYq6clcD9FnBK2dhALuGFi7zwcDBIEJJ6Hi8melz4/Ovy89HyvhN7HCObV4VkpBhV2eIYBDnG/xddAOpDoCyo11hPkixuBWCWfchNUnezwgO3svzzEnIvQQAFnh4JaCG17TwXOoS0npdBkieXg3IDRDU@gNO86XZmomvHuzMvsuZhAwdHe8X4JJD6uP0seu7@ATic7pfgo7AcdTeAJ1gkFMw2zNmhVLbvp4FHRIBqf3@i6rQTeqBCD0Tm7kBZcqiGmUShCJFKtvtypwjj3rFqNJR4ScyIb98UQk9yLQsVEGTsOV96A8zu5HEf71gSiio/FMiZtw8PlBQzJkf@Yb2wzumaMJZMNU0TDM/gI2J8hcvmiSBsXSoAz0lHG/6@9J9tu21jy2fwKGLRFQOKu3RQUS7Z140yc3ImdxSMpFEiCFGKKRAjQIm1rzpl5mB@YD5hPmYf5lPshM7V1owFBlrJMkntPck4sEOilurq6uqq6qhrvGEi7JAME/Q6FGqiio5qv97toBUW/Ryo0jeGfyYf0B@8NxgtgzmzVajRQhyUwwneB6oY7ocwG9I8kFgiH1GU9DoI3I6dpdocqf300nQ4c11V1qGwCauDIcW@p3gtGueq1fH0Clg6VJTt8rNRukmD06bKgzJJ5qc9oZA7@003oj6ug4dQNaBOlrsgULbZJZ4Wro79R1ZIMFRg8QZOMIt@Lg@@ef4vKXLO90cm9/1S/57WF3oCYVRb2u2Oqd0p/Pj3lArDAKKUGoCSURBeNhlFHeZPowpdQ8BwLUfp82qrPA9rWASUgx879sdknbsazcGFCD2z4L18dvDj8@ugIOCdCu7Gzub3VKekkWd9V@e9r7Idyd1KOsAi2cRDT6JOxSp6A3EMrxciQnZI/EXCjgQUxB7maNHqJ6Rq0V0bWTwn5GA43xgs3JuiAZweIB9uiPBr3S4peC1emEICTGaqLo7nwFyTh@yAqEQ2Iq8p4SbO2wH@wbb381RLXAxICEhKjVLNAuaBcEN@zj5QjKOk2lGYHi9RtRcecdE3jgCxd5B2LsbP0S2jbmMWYHRVxvdK0U00A4n4eCkt5TUx4Zf@V0oWInZdyfcGb74Te4PG1pKOj5HR@nBwkLwGNR7ommqNTm7MM@lhaPt33YIpWVnRPexYa810BitaeWI11fg9jNRAop@gy6Fm5hjs6HUi@S/JvfVxxrfdMqZiDA9vpCMXKb6DcouFIKx2VBkR@q@QSFrelc5Uw1i51HyVV5LVOR6HQmUHTL8IHtf874qSg/T1QOKH1FFtGyr47YZJaZVyB9kpICS/VeYJxiJFi03z1Om3mypyYcz0wOaRZcPQMoEBmZ6levKYkhUOnAAFI5GjXMNevdjg790Fzemy7Uh2PQyb9i8ixZK9QW8W1dk@rJHNV1QEK/nAtlw1NRnefQ0XrMfvIJaJwARfrLa2Hsc1trLVclbujsUpGD73KiTTP2RE1T05NWVpq8UuaJGOXGehsRyCKXt14IrdqGVksMwxfTrXcjpnd0hywoA363EdAC8eNHvjsipvNlsj50F9RBjvMsY06M25Fkm6uR06X4wDbeTggywjeBJpc4nYx5tYpzV7amuU8JKcQ7CT1MExzBCLzdeuAddpkLzX0ZKZEetXQfz3hTPMBm7hUiTon8xAIzdD4uvXCXyLM47uN2047X0O07mf7fz6h1IP9hHfKaBqT5g69oKb/ME4xotxwYB9KsST@l7ai0fCyFi7gD/VVk5GrJI6gM1CCySKh/@pGhYDyS2ZPSC37ZKKNSI94I/MeKvEFn3jt6qfX@CR2Zg8GBcDBGzxOFTEIQUa5CY/wrq82gg9zw30bBrOBaZaD3XTgR2gBIvF7OqFtV1mvJINc30/iYAlSaL8RLhrURtf5bHo@6T6Zjv1ROA190BUwi/aCFyA@LukR83@OZtPLmK5ioQ8Do9BgmT5zBhPO6IW/9dFYx8jyFCdB5Jgn4slseXDOiQjIeItuZpbmmZRENcqn29J1NjbTSqVshCN5fLXczo1111tFlfnwGBuQZbWfO6znKMWEQl@M8MbOtQK9jxUwYOxZNct3b/AJy0C8Cyiik4AMxAqYayfg5iBQO7gR4uPBojqgdHYzTOUTPA3wMpPYoddVHy9wBE7/CR5KP7JaO02jKhvyF5jSDh@WN6O7vf07Qw8A/ALwW@tF1FJECJTQd6jy@cQsM0teSoBFX1RWRU0AlOTpLByBYjvONNpd5FvNfl7ehA1yMoGtWTK2XaNKXJEOCN94i5fTBZbTXbrWhw9Wxaq4lBkCd8SDxGneTLDBbR6atPjxHJGNN8iYnkjLjgH0TajqA5bw9r6cA6cJMmfhvX3FtNt3nbUcAr0ipybjhgDHVvslxTiIzIMnK9MZMGM7hz3xNqjEyTSq3BF7N/KOwiRfRbjuu@6trqZMbN5irb06INR6S3xcdkp5eHJEk8UYOTUBDaEKRc@azPNIXHhdXG9ed3kLHm7CWeqiozcVPd8DXvu4Kb5Fn1G10eglRbBjvsuOfn/chYF3b@Yg0iaL@F3iGF1kGd0lPxpN5dCksXR3DBH1Cew5fAwAc9jvAHBnzs@NSM37Y6nsmepTJl8i4hNTfWNYIPClaIjn/5iIjI9INJPirObBI0zsSqdJrVoP89XiB24Qg1WCWmoLYStiOlk5OqJ88kOniw4rLeRE8LRvHrLrNPEaYZTHXQwMcujeXdZapx1uaaFbAlmWSn2sJRXRDD@Puwtq5RoqYIkXoEKP6BpvOr/7qH7pWKActMC16bP4kjarOBjXWgNo4B/zU3eBMnDaldTMrKjsQugSa4C1AGrIaByw9oTSXzhjiscDdllGINrzawf/rEkNTAC91dTYxiqLwRKLuIJuXm2uVdvnKilB8W9EvyxFFnVJXYIGAoYY6nstaAEzZBL0aJim5C4m5WUAlTmCil4LlyW8pASbqUthwXdEqhTY2DRKNItK7Jpt1AobAcGiuEwKCMgsxUXSVmCjK4TFKLFdPJ60BAjEivYZ4zAVMitZHOqZYwTCI0GrOcpxy6o2hYLp48amm/mo6Zu@7jaNr838V8CPhvC41sp/3Wlmvma6bbezVTM1AR@u2WvmI6DCNQHWXOGX/UfBD2b2bO2WaCgZGSlDXIEnqEpdot5W/yG29ijsV8kYqj0z9lipX12@lCOT3/vjubwtyRTf@eWDVb6RChBJLk@Jz1Q0hcP6IAmsNu70OCpUdFUqNx0Br1Ta6dD65tXRUSavaG@pXF0ugtlms9lEGu6ZadSVFy/aL8JpI1u6MZyPx43o8rPZN70GsX68GHscTx8pBTqAGYE1EdensxFfJYAwQFEsXZNISVT158OhmbMfD8lw7mDWuKSE21u0/4Ta7eKbV2TgoSZlfz3DAeL4ziy9@C59ljOlFXUSArXRKfWtrQ5wAD34YoiewPqwhBpDvqz8aWDbcr3997iB4FUYNFmUCNd9nzrI2p8G4/G0an07nY0HGIp@7ypf4ejIrNDkInjIReGj85gSnlat4G04NgJXsYhJ6tic2pfUxQQqwzhmWf8qGD1bRI59/L0NuwoMeQ2HuYaZjquWPbJdSTt@h2aZDgHsO5W@8COnT3jKF4adXhZw@gQQrbeqhapPpohLV4wIzm4vjUgtBrdO2QBg6C6JAiorOk0vjeSG4hq59smiNUQcNrkNgQmTetytBsYy/X5c8W0yHN6NKVJCeZ7Y35whkkWaVqAsP8An5mP@pxos66NcxgqWb/Dah@t8Byt0sUKp9LDv/XjpHBwcWA@itTXr4OAQHmo16@DwwHqKLw4Prafw@xB/r3jtzc0O89yn7nt4eaheXlmH0AYZONf657On8BO@eRiYhP7COMUPGt6DaudB19vb78SN44NDjBuHp7/923/87d//s3EgP/4LfxzSj@PvdaF6vd540H//YOWqg7@Pn55WHvSOH0SnlVEHqQzZ/dez2B/7hgNjvV@6JUhnMA57NwXuaA@OMCZvQfTYc@AfzwMN7MMHfjpJ0sdZ@ohpOdPq/jg696m6RS3se5WDysoKPO15lX@pkO1E3vv6/Tt4b7nIyylun1CLV89YBy@fPH9uZr5Grk/S@zDANC14PaIcm4STOIRBnZXVnXO1Y6tet05r1pkGD10NulwwCyKrmQzMvwqQanTkF0Lnp6I24MEomb7ZIs/nJBfxiOQ7ZTrn@7d80VQeDh7xoQ61sQYMD8t32F1aQi9x@AAunsJ4tePW1uZprVwul/SdXN0@sTnqLaK@9B1N6hiXzmA4EiiCJQNjpzvSPMQFNIjIKJfpxqaVPt8s5kxQtSaNiRXucsWQ59HeRAMpaTbHFm6O50cZCxU@ugXLiucUCICywfKuR0oAAEV47RHjsviy3TgK@uFwqY/d8VKEtHfYKzFqa9UaXgvasuxZz5Zx3R@mDQJCUAqgdDHYaL5BRt4UyobE7XiM6jeIG9eJ6kzyT1sbNMHaKSWajpejMXTmkDtPfAncCTDvymSNJyqaC3vgmr1giJe984rmCUvdSRHuXoCmiEkfFMwBXlE0xrRQLPDxESQlRIT1gBKOXFE2xGgEZzxhJ5bpEB5hw8dALr6OjchwDbdUIShUalE5VlecCR9YjVzXirgkYhV@pwfARB5kgiR9WO5ayxwFRq7UxLd7QmkR3i6HirSkp3RlJdm0VvQBLEiVF3hAhodjgBQsWafrrIA1LK2z8eRMj5@P1GK8EY/Oz/jCOeqmzWfkwLF0Nypim7pjd3Sbjat0@dXETwS90TSOwx4gK1mqaaIsfOy/PoNWTyol7kyoBQ/qEMH4ajXSK8ocnyKlYBFRiDjDew9NuxNFBZmCeKyIZ2J8NlzOnBRPppMasdxekIR9duLj3u8rXhzhMS157xNgN3cEygMfVKoJph5OVIIbOaOkqU7bITyhvzyu/3MtevuEMzHzCouW2AUASBOHnp2TFElpi5oSqIEsUgRGckEWDN7LEOY4GIVJpk5VkgCw5zOP4kqhHhf5GQJsYjeHWfTVp1XZM/aZM8G3cg9Axqu@AaPdcSX@toj21GBwV@O7D3VNHhKFdO1cpw/NjxQ4JtSwggF9uHyr2RmizRX3OspjhtkkB1lStdJZ@GgP1LiAyPxilWJMqAHhFnmc1I4BG@0cNoCd5pZByoWbmeYNAkbiNndy4lE59PJ0sUhwjXkrelGQIhFclXRUyfv/734zU9mbYYgsLD4ohXQAe3Tq5qBTOeSbLFyBl4ES1CU/G7DG2RyTorH7hOwomEUl5EVqdKrhyHWlhi4zXCNJKaIUHfDzuGLOZa6qGm9a@zRbu1bhqKL3KrbIMSSdyJWQI/l6jzfz1tamapeDhujojX5dqegmCQ7SPhNqdgTltL36Q0QPemHQNT96cq6KSEPp8IrLqzGLZAHCZaZxaouOaKSc6YlSgCT2VTiYJ9Pnya8v01N6Yznr0y/pxk@QC3wQg0VE8N2GPMEjesC6v5ZagHwgBEbAPlR@HMBzqcSSh2iY9ot4dDhdOM3qiX1iV1tbu65NerKWw8r9GDSjcj/ghF14a6DonpQYkOzabwNm4bNeOBgEE5UOFKpKb/pTV5o9RnP@e83uYr5k1SYmHtgGL49rMIn0QnBNz9HMH1349PjF9NXMXz6HTYh@fjnh@XyJ7X0FmxFeC0RfvuI1ejAAUcO@Qj05pYk7DZFClnyQfPoJiQacDM4QFwoQEFxDAPepxx9nB2ugwRw/2y609Ez7JkzqGUsoMTvynvHByVmJ75y9wEtRu/wOaNMxLqWVR/qUuylZZAT8oHzMjLdcg0X9MZ70BJPMOYTKXiuExzcXc62qNQYCbSqV6@NDmbJP7pmGPj4TxSbpn3cv5uMklJFdG5YaF1bKX79L6qS6MfmGK3jJZJjHnTEObPc4hFWa6jLEqFIsiBKmWjH0R4VuGj@ZHVOhQVQVzjzR3iD6aF51PjI3LN3vK1UDE0MYBzZKOcVxlgx1A2p3Suk@a@lR388oHwgHIAXBWI3o7mNizVfmHOMMY@oKYiZ6cn8Lnf3vWcnlN3TakGJJ6aUY/QoiA/OwVNcnz/aq1ZRDbEOrBUrhy6@nF4FotqJOGMqrcXEZ53P83RXWWzS3jPRnoEp5Dpuyy/3MQssIh8pl00CnFmJoZzZngcZqCiOmJEEsJ5LYfMaztHTFgdGFbIOVEijJMOeFbCUx6ZEWsDdo4trmWdVixLVPrpLetARERYGmBoqpyu6Wbmxy6TVa9dIdTMGalSlNkd1KN9BUZi1QwjUZ3Iqo4DqiWj8PUQxXEZ74y6@GpiwCsli6KpWKyFezDnHNMte6jmK5xpcIcfe1IJxro0DQ7Y0xb10KWL45vDReJPtdJQyvWgcjYItZWZg9rP30HWs9rEDGuahlbYhjr/j5DPO6lkG6KsH/mGMXuNQFGnQyFhAQWRslXYhilBAbhG9tjZCoeatRdkviM9Qo8001re2WS53coScMAv0F4j2zQTyKGV4LwMINhUSOVasrQWy37360191gls6Mr9AkDRw5NUoze16NInQmv81K3ShLNgXHguYt1/qZBmqylbR5D0I7T6NcugcgsKSBad2gM6q9JgbeOIBh6KSQbM5N3bBYP1SG7j@S/VvhWPkqCAVoAaGppAOUz@gWYp5gkRAomJIWaOVhXAFU61COwl5SUY3ERUJthpLVDt6SrbrQIKRnhXbp2Eov8ZwlhlWx0GqqLERWubCa5WCWS7Rm0NFR0EdDuLZSxa5hDxazQwPalkuhASwO1tNNZtiVOZyVFUtgI5N1TsYoVPQziGI4Msg4mTBzzpMuMCF8SYiXLQWWiZb6okL7AxeQEunqXCkWRJC9pnJIaqFppHifTzTmi7FDVT@GHwqGmOaCXAgnxFF1@pEUmtJPRWgen7cQKRn0/n6o9CfNxF1JVa6OvokWeS/ebvFebO49y7iB1gbcffBv2OdYUwpuTPcfa9UMAL7H@y@ZKeAfJlCKV0h0IDtw@zhx5brre6leV4@TLt/crdkv6nHicjcYwHYMzJYim6qgJybkg2QZeFYOthTk/pM2TKWkc/fCCkHFRFDympnUTvUyixQzQ/1VkfGEqaGEEt@D5si9iKIJ8ehq2ufYdNig8PuQItNJr22xWoQKEVc8xp8S4ndvyJnyhrKSeQTWale6lTEIPDQIlrEOZ35yJxErPZJjh319eX2eDuN6yXr@00Wyu8hlq3eWy8qrZNNeTcWz1XIEssX6z2zjt5XTUgMttGNryG1cqGTAJ5UDUAwTNEYP49SYL1zLPHL7@WLfn@LLH3VjWP3Diy@rGv39rBCzmgox/UIhJi0gtfpoeKN6ujyxB1i2E9KQV0Xs4f6m2f5g3aj@poX98WXgVlpOKk@pW3xd0G1yOZUamlClQ7I/FnaEvJbX9Jkta/vMcq4vaJ7vdBte/3Mb/sfehhsaF5jw8padxpj6P@f@H2HuMYXieKe50@z@aue@@p1tEpadO2@1LPu@1dr/ZPtk8bR5stjd@PLHclLebze@ncHfpPxjeWunzI/wAL/W1a@35f3yHhbbuiovG57nwaO0cnAErex/ptvEUss9@Gd/U7W7tSzv1zyq/qG8vwUPrXYbIDlZPNs9Wew08X@780cSP8zTFS183NRqRHlVZEPgs0BxkSe1fBqnTT4xdofnSAJKHc8aSHHnh0ZrBDA6zyzaO02RVYCAOP/D20CugLoI8OoubZ6iHCYJ5dHgiAuV/0F89bgSrADdhQt/qAva7UX0SnNOqHQTKCWkQFtnD@tbeHR9JmkoNAA68QSJmezKDeqFQx1jii38u9/8xNaJKR7ZkrfCNj3@5WxTdsUd2RX/t2xFy@R8OmkXJFYvW09gupLA@iFmWOJJGEVBwhL/KJgEsCWjMT2coqCDN7318V68cfiG3f8eqcatPjXU/SHucmwON1SPlpb94DGsrPCCtKJ3sCrVM56PbW2oX8C48c4wjJNR0TWjMDmf9ygn/qvZ8nnyJWWiaGBe7YSzUjRAlus1Lnx0HKBM8jGQGJQAdjCbTxp0txgIbBgrg@nfL/w3ABreZwpDG3ShGBr73zh0eWgcRBTishgObbqpJxgPXgaRP/M5axp6zc/9UfAcE8PAZMTnNipPZesLCq5JzOy4WlkijIMcLlcy1TiDFfH@uKLCPwm1loXhxnRjjI1x6sKEiHfbdYqagFo2hxbQLdXD6TRJy3PUuK5AP7M1KCcYTBKHhuDhYDoi4OY4/jUFxJplyQuCI/0pnaYvqCOCZmaFeJMDjiqYzC@IdvTNqsetR6eSN81rGTdck8frziO51dy2EaE4TWJsbu3glzn7XtK5ZElSB@hxgGDNkEBBnpA5nRZegKYQx9PeD5T3B7kSLEikv7r6Jsue3OjhEY3dk2DkE6@47IUJFRiEMRXAmo3RO5DdGUXVDKn25qO4zmuBAivCOJ4Hm9s7GwQQ7fiq6GDazxRtN6DlmT9bNgi48@RirEexm5xb4@BtMBbvFQKbMsryoiQ6w0u1/PmY3Fq2XCIdQGVmpIAFZ7fK754@O/r84NWzp1UQUzaxeExhSbqsYyCXP6/R9@EYMzUwGWEVXr713tYGE7kTVyuP0SLHoD820b5mAqwaiOM67gFh5FQ8qiZ@FtywFaHaPhlV9XH45XT2RicuxuWGoMzptgNbIVet/HIZQ7pi7KuMJJhJbAB1cGAqcns2BsZzrdCNvAIwINytmwBFjpF/IuXae/drNb2mHtFTDRhrrbbPRhb7yTgExbPy1XyS4bYVWju@VQEmh8f/zNruV4gv1O2Ode6hHt/pe82Ojtt768zd9/pW5CFC4TDiXk0Pl2r@nLlEptmAEJe8nFXI5P/8d8XtXKVJdMZO4mL2f@udp5IX15mpP@PrUp1K3IfJSqDau3oSLJInnG3SSzq6Qm86WMq1909Aqx4478w@Isd9D3v12lrf89bd99DlLMIslBEww@AVtOh28N0w806HiDVOTiZ4B/Iqhu599@LzT2HK0U8siJPj709XHzSqlYrrdnAIvkfxfU@/fPFXtPLP3DpZ@49m0wvBy8zXndRhti/i4@YpQV@1cWgNXIXAOUdBIqOPD5ev/NEXIC05FR9QgG5JFBgHkxLu@RJf1kHfJJS58H4QE0eenZ1c230/8qjU@SwYdthWcRV7b52R20ngz7nZxSZ04bXb1HoClTz0asphPZzAbv3pqxefe5U938JWvYJVUVnraeIAQiGCcfDVAd6IlCEd4CpEVQlH6xHBwH9rFXs/O5a9hr9f6Vxd3QjP55zTFYSfSkrAA2deFYqbedentDNLqWAZBR6@4K3tL89e2VWoiylY8OUEt7clMS0OYvVUH0xuyCloC1y@xDKet7GyQu@wyjz2vHaz6WJGlCtoLcYrzKFZXlizztXM9waORqQfhQUX9rTr7QYHssSN1la7ubn9yXQGW4SHd6KvxMBCPNRa3obJcgVkw8BTl/@sgJwMu6l3f2N158vw8J@/23259dTp9z5r2VX7h5jc9meRCcDMv6yzWAQ8dib5XgkIjFzs@43IfzNtbAyafZA8W9uDYHsz2Gmu7/Q3g/Xd3u7ubn@4sdMb7G7725v9XgPzjVOV@kU4ASnJZvLHbod36/YmwWyn3dwdDlutre3B5u5wt91cX9/o7WwOmhsbw52Wv76@NWjv9HZ7H5faUnhKwGAV38W9I8@BH94s3JWu8Xap7f4f)

This answer is based on [mauke's code](https://github.com/mauke/poly.poly/blob/master/poly.poly) [adjusted for polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153744/wait-what-language-is-this/#comment452208_188756) by Ørjan Johansen ([test it](https://tio.run/##NY@xCsIwGIT3PsUNBVuwxTmaji4dK@L6m6ZNaExDEhERn72WFLeD@@64u1NQi6CI06nCrt6hwVCrsAhDIRSdml@g/dnMFLUdQSVvWhBeSnr5mRijqumiX63jxN3TyxxhjRQDnC4ThIHrPnH0zbQNkayQaJEqMwPiRtoxqi0Iyh6kLXdrZcxhckzFgbEEl0ud@acdlUgL/7q6dWJ2sr@8nbyS13Q3Mmwffg)):

```hs
class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a}
instance K Float
l a=length$ show a
main=print$ l$ k(0::Float)
```

[Test all GHC extensions on TIO](https://tio.run/##dVXrcptGFP6vpziWNROIQQOyYqfCkKlsJfbEiW9q06mqyCtYBONlFy@LjWNrpj/7nH0R94CkWh4RzYDYw/nO5TsXpiSLnp99osCDsM2irLEN5j0EcUamjMI9kTzms6zRgzdJzlTMYk7BF0lCuXrTaFA/EmByaNqd9z1oOiBzPot8MP00Xdp7Udm3NlTMP77SGVHxHT2NFZWEZZuoTg3qIidZfJELRWsA3RrAFzKL/WNMdk19DfP@lxpMn/DZOVEYF9/w0rHe1SFiTuTDz1LpWHs1mEGhKA9ocERDggxf5ozWIPdrkL@mKYv9ir0jUZtXx6rL62ueHFE/TupCtGtrJL4ILhIh0yjOkkuaKRn7KhZ8E27XcY/gU@EThvQENS7rCnxVuahPyu7@FHBEFFl3gMrInGmaTVj8tuGYFh@ZIGpVpTXDnbpIzu6oRH2sUOkCZ2Ejgd062CWdYrblEF09cEWK@lS6dR1xLjIVxsVZivEpITcd7tWx/BuPfRFseltCdmsgQ5qkjCiKc3FDGdsE1RLti5QGw4eU/k5kXCa4CvD52YuTVEgF55KyPKDO8vjp@LB9crY6lTVqf8y5j7m1DwXP1Ks3C5ZXoiEtVPuYShoIfyVDjJKCtQeFT9OyDVcvTnFgczKj7WVC7eGx82hO7u6/fbsY3gyHf5rzdbNXkbhfBII2MifGSAj3KZT9GgdAXA@fSKBVMQLR7yOMAyae507cBKlTD6YJB9Wv4f2PxumCPix0QymSE67ojEqYuH3AFejwcuHR8tiCYrtoeEHZs323/5j3eqg8d6hLpRSyuY3chx@4m/OMhPScylDI5OSsBSHQa5x7P7r@a1BqHhLGHuemJ4G/ZHGSLZiEVQBVSI9lSMsXE9eaO6/i1ojpTfVXMm3t@BmqyXkRlAxqFytqHjM8otVmc@6ErvZdd27xJFugBe0@gP6h6wRaHyagl8IQrPLWgb2u4zOSZVppDYhR@SjjI7rrfQayDPym18Polt1x46a5pC0oPWohpPGyOKEbB5UemTszd1TKnsrbgdlsjk1z9DSGhuc0vMK1nIdt4mb5VEmCi8aa2rienQJl@AFxIpi60@@FIys/4DDsBkb5TEULn0AcLAbSjnZ@PGn//vO3fmC@cxcyp7L1xKiCSXviFi8l33VHOPIGDpZh4X0XL9vA/WHg6jFwWRu4fw38lOIzaln7eO7ihTo2vrf3x1tbGtNwlzUNq7DatmFT29Cs6zi41o0bzer1KvJ0Q4kBx3qioCwrdnJ1xH@i73TeMi0QQA7MqrFH9tipkiRGhEQaUWnmkhK2UNdN2H2rsZZWET7M08Fo3OsNivRCB93UzNsPezv71s4PXXdA29LdjN5WDCck5hUF6Rb2mZti2RRylycjC7Ywa5xLc45lR2H5iR/lLRiZNiZoPc0Oml5zjOWaQ@M/).

Answer (score 2):

## 266. HTML+CSS, no JS (Navigator 9), 12540 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]xx  >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4o'6o@ ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAb
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
<script>onload=function(  ){document.body.style.display='block';document.body.innerHTML=typeof InstallTrigger!='undefined'?259:document.documentMode?262:document.querySelectorAll?257:265}</script><style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51 #a",_"[];l{t}8;rext7095?1&&1PLers$/  \nu2FAC0::FloatV$ f Cr=B51 16 4 6>E>83nt:k:2:~-<le._ngtbontgerminPrsharExu Uatafint 22w;ry ctorbody=>+pdisp se66$t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g( ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad(Const a)where _>>=_=mempty-- <<<<<<
>instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance K Float;instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);l a=length$ show a;q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$ f 0$ f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a};g=[here|here<-""]--[|] 
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEAQIsPkB3ua97CaHZN@@d0A0ugAUgGoCVWhUgQSazY6Z8casxlJ45fGsYyStdUey5ZXWjrDWsV7JYSkcIb06FH7SD2j5ZUOxofkHs@eczCoUQIBkj0YRCxKorMyTJzNPnjx58utk3XA7v/hFBD/s2OmO213HY57peqw5sC7NgcZ2xuyJYbmZ9KokIdT2oD3smbbn5qUI0xmzzSt2YDesJvgxz7kwbeudOYCwNGP9gdMeGD3mdQwPXiyIxfbM7vvee481nF7PsJsuQK4ydmxAYGvYuGBG3fUGRsOzHBuC1hh7YXeNXr1pMIAwB/2B6RH6DAMUjQuKMx2SZeyZM3BNTL5huq6DnuuMbZq9vjcuwUsOIIyB5RxuP/98JvIGY58bkLN@1xzN5EVPsZeWOWjOxNB19tXZ/v6sb5p9qTo227@dP32VvRi4RteYxb/Gtoeec@DN@mfYdtu0DZbWNrT0bGCW7QyMW1HW2cA0mi2ra2qW3WAq65jdvjlg6MNazgCqzDO7uVQuVduexNQaGDc3CZxBW/Q/zBi0XQh0Lk1wmlATfctsstbA6THDdq8gJX0jNYFHtBvT7NCADAKjsTcuxG6azLWtft/0eCAU1xxQMKTMupZ9IXHuOx44zWHDstsAZwJd@0OPyuRKDYhWYn3Bwxo6WISowMEgC6dOzwzXhQvMC7l2@2bDalkNThxz5Jm2C@V1NWZB3V1Z3S5rml2IMMHeSDDXYUM35FXvGh2toUlIXEyF9S66zGKNfp/xICgGZGk/lWNmz3ljsXcQ3u24bNTvMdfqQbDXcFot02TvzH4HorNeU2o6EoNPoz9TsuBt2QQY24TS7R5/A3TzkJx2C7LWZPUQHOSD8kwlNmwHyDdgttHj3NDoj6n0gCaI0XIcDf2bjunaUY9dOYMLVjcbBhYbE3PNdssYdiFFq4XVAXxguaznwBMq0WaQLYjsIS0QNyYmzS0IJuNXr9mHhonV6yC7QF37tXw1MIA/Bq6oR8/qAXdYXtRlpuFaKLEgimvaTeKMfiDLHChtuNLZpQUND0gxHBBu1xwQ6xNehqUAlEbAq8rVwPKAI7AU2@zYNAbsbGCaMc6nptsw@sil4SQhMQdT8LAgGjHm5ma0fLQfBQblMTSjDww5WD37zheSwbQiW64V4FuU5YJUfr7HrpfP0c1lJjBxf6AYMVb8wNzk@bkJ35FeT7YHNxJglYAqXZZ0@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@CkH6XvLMlYeHDjQkFDWuBmt017PbQaIO8cGyIYjQaZt8TggpK4nogimb7G/JUReepuR1p@cls2tSJ@OrRJA0U8rz2RFdooHQRarsKOhmqfnwswJrWAMQS9OQzqQPA5Uzi8msEmcrAa3lBFnwNAJjMHJmNoQdSDRj4qmM1OsCzmDuby0XeCc0mD17h1EGyq60gacyMXnqclrRk4IXZWIhCxRq9jQc6V0RVmvKgyg973I3ZcHtzEDtBFqEjCPlqSUMD3rsHZ8@xnTlIgZABWgSZDuH1AJrYKSrF0HH5ahc11kBTDqoI6gykBrR84L@O5/XdPPQTltcZ1jXglOTZYHzgHdnILElvMLY8h7vrXacOYtmF9pn0U0g2hnVrNFMg8gvq8I0rXYIC1nJZEXrut0PgOiXackFgkv8uAoeCZBLchIL/ygBIQBoQSmm5JIr3Qaicju2GIk8xpZxgMrZdOQYOjBiQ5gtU3qaz@Qa8ZnOJYOHMaEmESrqDBjnUkE6K6BGcsiU9miraA/MoPZJl@GkZXdeEpz3sdvF1aHMpp3BdIcaupUePQLQplJzV63ethuXVeCh7/FjoFGwJxnioNrVQZ4pBnEdiMK2BQAEY0f1waM1zTknZVWJQkEc3Uwmbg4Ez4Ol6nYFzxcgDwaQwUXedHkp39pIULtSgYVhr2Ti8F30pdaXGXBUi6FNJX45GtTeOZSvX0aWlpWg@WoIec2lpC1yb6NpCVxxcW@RSyYVwGrooRoJcGFqhGOhXjd5UfMyjWBWbwwh7@3dWXzEq@fxqNWFUdPFM4zMGdIYeA6BVfACeaKxYRGcsJpeuoKBavTVd@l3s9U4bA6sviPCFcWnwd0GFVSIDVJwzwIFBAZWXu2nSKw5Au4DBQKOjDKLnldR59fz6vBk/v4kmMHasYBTrUChIT@lp7YEzBDUkVlnLq3o1FqusgvJRL0ZT0RVFyakwjIORSOyzXCxucGorURN6Q@X8PApEFfSpNDoDwjdKpGOxgFSQD1R4QNdWotp1DtKvx6qxeBTixqIJGLoVo1GgTAOJ4FKhsS1NEejo5EtOmN14XKLmDaNS/N7qTsEPB73T0Y@H796h7OI46gGHdYcG1/L6AiB5YPuwGgbODFr9oHqLoRydSuNzp8VHRbv4Uz7cl8wR1dbnR/vlkyIl0zHcC9Ap1DbCJkFXBqoMmhpIg@6waUrzYEBsgKsxyQnOHWDi7UaDqQ4jMLXBMxHqLhpsATaQNaR4Okzt9qaL4HYgv7tTZSAk5E8x79JfGn6WOPjcPAVJ7oPE3j09nJoi612APsEabheVb3XACwCvyRXu2aRHMMbIswMao9mgYAJvgX7ZDOYCbMdWURb6wzknnBCfEAEI8kNtCzUJawoGEbesEQyJIzifIlR/1FhR@991bBicmtpLkoYyA0GOs1WmNlf/P@aKlNZwJ60TNH1w9rtGA@T9NLpzmZ0DQpBAyeT8kFjhFuLZwQGN4@8rI6hSDcNG@jUtGqcOLbeD5IWxBPYCgxZQFQepOLlDVDtgDdBy20Bpc2R5fNQKLfwUozw1XCWG46RtPs5ALkMdGTPlz9yRAus0YIRvgq6MoXy6hJXtS2vg2EhkrQyoQRQVsA5mkM8jL7DR9vZBem8xfechB4rd8tZDtA1jnSVuw4XWZTtdp@2wFQBA1tQ0ztgHNs5wwijHM/rQoqx3RKDttgND/WkeNM1gzjS7Gow3DYRMErz2BnoBNr/QE4AFZT49@G4Z1BA9k0pB/v23FH2CQoawzJYRPRtsAiBWAbrIN1iT3zX7nfFgip1cR8ybeDR5SA2Tz2QZoEJCrkQLf0dRw42c@0A794Oavmte2cs0JsDJu/C4eqr0U9oKbzZQwsiMN/r6pJhCeqvCJ/WLgus8OSW3gqkCtdVzPCP5lQYiGn8k1JBVi8luMroUTaoq/soUxNIllmyal0mUUhPMo7LZmIt7ZJqNJIZi58Z8x1zy@IELSHMOH5t@oJj86dMgiDlb/nY8joKdchekzTMNnfxZZ2hKZqPjMPkchhjhksnQQXRgrKwC5UEBxHFJEE2sCEmeM4RhXdPsWj3LO6A5@66NYxeNhLeGUkuE7oK8mSA4tkxQyPmEw6STwXn1SR9ltzn8CUhywgpDfI2TdGA2kysTbM8cZwDjSpfpNKeQDkjfEwFJx@03NW8ECHisMvXvrt/PPz/aK9eOt8@eFpNDd5DsWnWQEU2z1oPBbBeaw4IP5g1nCMvAO5bt9CwokY/y3UX3xHE8rjzgwsHDPhGM6OM43KsdHuycbJ98IzJHPbrVG3YNzGN@eQYgwHFKMHeiaTh1B3QLe7gQEygXRztHhz6WL14cHmzX9srHR2chNG@GXcvQR8n@RXtRgb5AEKZrKU76o25zekWHhqlTswhC2OCYq8BgbMpUFX5V9OOJ4qhMwwBUkbF7VFWcBTZwnnvA0npqY6NZN3I5M9tsrK2tt4xWs7mW1nOZVi6TzqTgZz27YbL3BK6q5ohmbsDFZ0VwAgnTgMzTQ9fWfA0HhqIN0FjGc/MVhN6RuUYmY66vbRgbjY2NDSO93lw10rl108yut9ZSKTOrp1r1nJ5bvTNzoWygajV569EMELQ6nCygQBB@CjymmgPPPOh6V6yZTqezjUxrYzXdzKTWmvWNVCbXrOvrRn3DTLXWVvW03myk9bwfF2dUQUp0oMJQq7RBNfWDVB0CY5LfmYarmFYZ/WVoIXCWV1HE9P1lZBw4iIA1DBiKRWScmhX@GfT3l5Bxikb4Z9G/hwvIE02WXgNPAZgjQFxH1gZ133MDPYMV5Km1VRCVQn7OC18cSWC@1lM3iPwK16BD5bvWdfK/9FqtKe80eV@o2JV1J96r5M1XoKfXfkVhbwXNBQ7wrRE@vnI9F9@toLnAAb4Mx4cr3vPRzYTMAw2QZQkZrpDPxTUTMAcwwLROmMKr6pOwHIUtWlIXac0NXhgpwL1BuPlqee0NX62oicVy5GbeQM5AEzt0QH8@tHDevjXVYqRgBH4uyf40wvRE0iQkPVkmYerl/PUdOYyICwPLvnBo4By4ailNzyCWAEXvons7ZguGGvQzBXorU7dDeP/Vq7foZw4AdrqzM3MUQNOeouuHrtZIntADJ0Dn5WB6Kncq@brZGsIoKFm3bHTfA6Zu5AiyVa9bi0CBErj5wH/OAcuzkyGMRNPamqb7w15cOgGZzedhzw6OCLBu0CBuev6fTRHfGw48iCWe//V7TaiE21XUMcY0FgwcNdu8Iv5oLawxERVf6Gd@7U56fSIMue5D2TBwydXoBo75qKn2VbVjDHo45BLVDQyKP8AJd/Aazzmfi/Gf8xPJMyLy9DoDs60ea8yBJtiZJRGeGA2yu47RJDLwobBlUqQBVjavBnPEB4UhhQd6nkUJzVm5YJOtAl5n6A35L@4OuK8arT5@72qiAjKVMeq6CSqyUbfMOyp9YFwMm44Kmh4VGTOWnQM7KT1N1qmtrnHBnTV0zi8@L@DAardBnxDPRWBXHRjb0KA0eUWP@/jCtYduX61DZXnQcOiNmkLvjhQGXf67CMQS@@cCx2KqWV36eUClB8xF7AIqHREatzSpIaJZM2TuGvUxDtU7n85lmCApOCBzio14PLWK3V6w9hveirQ4PvaVFH9jY35svpmKk2Te8CrJN1GpfAKZyiy2Vd1TsdBxWT2jq6abIedCie5PHU9cc0Bp3kZtdA0XWMsT1WFeQvXRz13sjj1TA4Zdg4nrDmafZMffArBoNVmILdGqG07XcrFpdxdJ0NkFuEmauJ2NfkJT0tY8wjZJZ3I7auCaLxechodLuQsY7QFSjq@i4jp1iHM0ZxHRGs4VfheqFh3n0uS/8zu6d3Nz9QCJpXaJJazG3B6l2biPU3E7EP3Mp@PF3Hx5je5c/@k24E9xhAdoD@Rr1@o6Ljul37vI0h5ANP47n6PDFLQMW6X1oLB7fjSRqT7TxCzrgno1um2nm821kwb8LKz84aCFfYJ4PlT6BdJL1@@XXr5@5Ni6eC4U@xfJwcV9dUdLEwNctA857@iB54kwsSi5uIAwksCdOPMLt5/KUUwtycfLiypg0OhcGWP/@Uv0LIuo6/cs/THp26D@YYSNHDi8AdfBf5nU1u5Orfkw8XQL7fp9hQhV7kXXhI6Mfm9VKUun9E@MoadSDxdWre7QHJpzZdVR/Y2J@9vvGIU8PFMpUYxlMduJM0I41xlAvRPjxwflGvtwfLtTwBhdCxr5vZrOXHnXBx29j0PuY3Aco@N2xLY97E9V7tQozj65m3Kdvt@yneZUJjHkUyVS7n59akqRd0363jm44oNBXNsqrqVSKaHfhOavp17uGnStBnHfWPx3KmHymaQ8gcXZkEHIOT@NyVQqVL114ao4qfkw6ZReNCNAwBsbSduyTW@Mv4uqZJ60rTtO91OqEIRu00L9DbRSXPi5rypv6UZiNxibzH24OHNSby2a9eAdkhidAvVw4H0XN4SnXh9UzSouWUMrbc@83j0PFJrIvS8V6OZpcolvneguVjzFjIqu5bT1O1skV2edutk1@GOUXbsL34a2eie@QGURejKtbeF6GF8Bm6yoRmbkVn8MxLKaMMjpmD2TXu8YHRjNN0PXfywEGjn4nROs0Xrjonh9CwSFjb9Tq20hVcpzbBiWecagbeK4pour4sJ3kXD2Z9XnEvegZ7RNfq7qLuk5merArcN8NDhxzp/0yPNdZw2Ixrd@3M0K0JguzLHrP@cifDZuQH0Oe/dP1c20@wZtVLqvoWvJuYsJ9@iKdsfp2B2zw3cCBW@LmgdwpMdPxN1VCMh/u9NgJJ/Cu5TClO063e5DKIvykUtLx2nNzVMZz2k1Ieon4R0bdQgQj3unAKGvJwJRp7@o3XTMIXRZruM5fVOlt0WgXZws4r@LpKi/uPPLzkLdOUMAFPGfvyz@e8embcPx@n161PrdoUs/FFWl43XzqnKfknkIV1ge33bE@dZsO/VGx7ovS3XT8GzrIunPCPHXO0e2/RAVLKbuobfWtYB4g7GG3FAMh5/i42BRlYrJJd5tBY75dZxnu8PBYIyU8ByHuV3naiIfpvdPBNO4fPUBHYtyIFYG5wSTNoA76/wdZHcsgYiFxIUMRko4KtyqmQKFRV84ozS1vTPUOlZX@c8ivWim/JSp0Prtp0yJim0PNDlohWZuwX@Kf6YWo@d2VnZn2HZvizs@Yd8EFQt/5tb0dhvPNM9UNK9U6IEMWzwW0TvdTeL2bXjWoOaG5p2rK5k7l1cITu@qhmPBowYPqMPhwmmzrtV3@S9TW@m5CsPtJeTbUOP5w2ZRP02zxddC0HWfptdzBniICFQKtTEw3QZOpaNE5voTlz620wbJrHbZBNiHnVuE26vWc6s/6PHUr5@bbQO3Vx5auNOyO4crAOvs4vV9SL8zNFzrO0PHM@fim13Avg/dM6NtNZ5OUd5H5lNU7MHjjym2R6/bxL/qWC6d3/Add8w5IZNxtkU@q4G@P2@0NjNdHxyMvntaJaQoib3fTD1g/h7xwIELBhhuzE1r3ky806dx45hcd03CWx7NzIrnXK6avwngruSvhr3@0BWP@anTPp3wFHXvgvzdKwvEovoWpDHrGF1v/jR2aGYWdC7RSU6ci7Tw71pdp82@m0sxUNGg00alfA7D7UB3fWx40CLsOQxMaT9woRQnPdQBL9hb4AlzlamWbXl3T/B4ngFjJP@JheGdDZ5CTB7ir/bkUzGoZ/MpcninBgN9@7jRxUPxnzoS4GIXuPCUDq2jMzg3H@Z7kYy5KxD6vYttXoXHa3cu@uSxS3XsoafiLv@7@pTsnX1Kno1y2RBrMOU75WcvYmEOoe2v9@mhJgwEh253PHEt3Hgww3iWDcraYlk8De2PJvZMMmlwQhs174mz3cfTUyTy95x5I57jMfQ@Dx4yQQcy7O2ZDVx5vDft584zUN2gK@uD0O2dmLhlYEaWzI@I0Q6dhtEF@jTvTeaU0M7pKyaDa6Nv1qF@uxPXfF1sHuI9wzMW6E40cUgjwMB1L69Y3bo5eEMzgiH3okHtdIaemiMahixmGN4KVa/R4Ao3TstNtZHZtR237zg2/yUhnIKH/uxuYQPdA/08fMVdw/3LU73f3EHadGmPLvl2E7PJD@4tKu7ArDtd/otFWCAObItvLjAGlukmDy17OCI/poLuNn@Yw7fxprR1nOZwO9DYriwYYwe7e3GzGt8q7M6MpEAlvjRcWvKfP6aZ2kn88F1FHWPQcHDtTDg@ceUsdCTsHjkebJXmWxPqUCkjEGhGY@jbFbgnq91evUc/C8ckoZo@Met45K5O50c9YzRPiZw@OiY8Zw5v@SING36WKccw6ond35HNDtmmKW716YcE@tVcNvGTe26ZjXdG7B5ZGrQimktOGjSinduQpjfBgZrTNVWvg3ssk563SGA8ty6GzQesdfkLKMOeiWvW0ys3C5nKcTvEEc78VfpA4A5MsXUbdwlC0/fdKHXV7YUsi@jh/2jniyR0zLXsGp7gH47UNoiz@/cFQOaHA1s8HsJ2x47rtazRUR/NODmDRfIFi5WBKPDgzQFdK4sKAfVpD7t8vqMd2tHVa9L4DrTBlgOuLolwz1RN@1IlE0cjf7lyYPh2ZBbW4ezmUP2e3aFXbrAeCAFq36Vnsu8eHxwenWl9V79j5hA3/A2tLq7uUVZ8PygguRZPUZ/SXrW79c29o53y4TZTmiBkHDt2D7RYEO13jLrpGUlj4TgHQ01vvtL39OzZYXxyaJkpu52B0zNj4eDd09MEZIR9cTo3OBx7H7i75YwWRj8o63psDvu9sGk5cJHIm5PSIkxnJoxWgZme8vOz9ypMDadvNs/GffMr6A1R7LoPTD67sJDPjUurja2IbRCMOMhENpcC6xxuQhyxAz9rII7xu5pvQEycR6TuxT8ZA55GozHEmTBArjECVBQjHo/FJBHrqXPFemidCCO5dKz2wuoXWMp3Ikd1QIMgeDQsoLBlg20WWTqdYrFYgdvoAPaDNjQ0C6xl@ai3Xddq25AFPwdkXglNr3DLTS6DYYrn461U2PL1KJ/K6zesyOS8zKpVnmP8UCLlUZ9sI53w6JVlo1pcjqpqdDl6budZKhqAm10Yns8FN6ZgIbP4EBkO6Mvtpjlk9CygZoGbloFuE802dQy72TWZ4EMo/4AbSOHWd85wu/Vf/mFTWLMiq209yzW6QBA0SAdNouNcbfF0fXL1@wZaw0IcVx2cSsfU1d1tBsN8r9HhRqygul7sn@WEaRxh/Q5ejvlkaZALzjm4YovHfD3OGDw3wZFNkXAQyy8UjB@HPRsUtqbXcTV2atEJ3uFgciZH2AS0vQEuyzQT7IA1TdzZSgezaRWy6zgXdFgLc/KXf8gNAtHxbHFs1k@eDIGFUsRT2DpZ4Wk0nCHk2kfyzhw4AkRBIhsNb4hr/mSHjvxjeGiZLBUBt6u@nR5Khhvr2d0@ZWqZRdHCHdrVKFgtZXn75POvKqlq8QPrJc3/@r1k7FoQTv5M3ci6coL5IIUbZKxwcAaCJ6FRJi@PZJ5gcHbdEiPEK14faJ2PMxkeX/d5zHH6frPBIQeZFgu4UZjsUNBN9ewb7OmRmTZiWPOKDPbQIUkb@0AyE@hCA4PXGKHmra64rAz5MrR66rEMJIhGjwxwccNudJobjc9glOURe8@on4Ixh55JwRsnZBftHfWKO/65h9XweZTknlkf0p7sy7SWzhSpOMu14maJXKDTOGh3rPLqfJROqeej9XIVRlGCqOfno89S6a@B6s4AYj1OYssrP9@7XtZKqffvXWPMZPkmWuDnZ0BMLF8fHxyXT8@2z16cQi3c@KJtn5@i82UNchEdjO04XbLoBnTB4cwnyJ/gbSIG0WZoLCaFjzASqKC1rMrL3BkSTVOx74k@L75rhsJvAwiZ1rKYFPQMwAUGMRtSDQs/7KNdOibiCttaxGUW9h/YgALC4CmlObKUSCWzIhBLBWI9kFRscWG3uN9DKHYvlrvJtjUXBCkWpFcJwnkR55Lg5ldS7r7hun//cnMsd5ebYO4oN4AGvn6c/e2Dwxcn5elofidPUre4kRFnd7lwxpbGh0S@MTEymSEi4jJ@UWYyReCvojPjJk1N78qEYgnh2OjxyMShlH9ZmjAmUKaIVnWrQgtRFMoB6jeoiMweLYbxSiiLfh8dQnfNixgIgX05QO1nXJMF5ghZh9Xw4xcDsQpy@U3vmIS4kNdRN6z@JPwWh0XDPnro8ja3oKsKeh2XwX@oV/Jd6SobMdGd6VWmsjR8u6bdhgL7sLEC76PYMieEvMzzLgf5RauekKfmG4NWzujIjDiSC7101@i7vjIYYc8dz8yzt0OHzH74wiTQL8igrMGN8FLVctOyZE4E9HYYpvj9FuE72D8tonbGVTOS72GeG9rYUQEQt4crDuZ7A7QbzU9Mc8OUnOSOsIHod5U0@@QKm2eBluCyS8u1QImnSmihjtMFSYmlEQVHm8pk8IVtd13QSZrQfYOG4mFXC8qJRuc4@WFO1WZyBHhSC1TGBJMlhHWLt23iQVd6haOK1zzyMsERZjeEM7q5pKpAubZl@waU82hRmSZe8swbDHGbZil6K4qfhTy51I7X64YA51gHPTeTH3/zd7hF0HMP3D8S7lFqB95@Xby1wP0bfoiuw9s/C97S8PZj/vYqiVV22wziJJ@BRYuFJ1@BOZ/ItwqGgsE3JU0FCqocq/urg2PmNtBCMVZoD8aGk7pCMeOPU5jVA864pIpGcJ7CpB4neJTKV8AnwFzAJKjjoFpD6ZmDqoIW8fLJJGYcF9Q02i9rjvgeFjKQ93aIhmFBE0tmM9k1PQmZVC99hGSzp43H9zjCWCwPglG6tPrF1/UG29zcZLLbMLpmMVvgDJJcNl6tyq@DjC4DrMRHCxUGcSDKJAaElUQ0ZdmI6zGMir1ZVI@iYGs6nN9AJVTIASAx9LZ9Kx@gczqCVMDMtjnySG0a@6MgkNq2E7II7SNSARHHjeZLZ9vk5EgezgKHWqkWrgb5JYLRNEhensexlVfs3Du3q8KMLQPu@9kc/rXB/U/m2LblnIVWjG4bVVVmTaJiadiTU9vByfR9yC1T0sn0alLPxkIcKgtUkF9s7@8BJbRwkBgN03rj9N3t3fLBF0fHp7eMaxFkdBYsyqKlzfi5qiUq1cARDfI9TdSd/eTps519n5ThXE2msxFisj95NpvzUpvN6YLUX/LTj7fTpoBbCemphyKmuTB1n/b538Y@CU2GAHf54atbqSqx65tKdbN0bkduJf9@nsHkiLaCzAWuc5fMJUdns4lZDC5HOMPLEVzNP9qv47l@PPDpORcTKwHCIxTAwX0sIAEkLelDLRKekIEjPgM0MWeT5rczuCT6@CwRmbENchSCPPPvccCmNbG@KMwOdgy307XqEnTgTTTFyY0G@VZxAnNDmtvvWp4Sk2gKpIhqEAgxRdzmMMqPNFqFV8hoMuFKsLssGfr4YhI0AsAXPR66HXbs9ENzW3um7zoBbYTtDfkSrcm@GPYArkWPExNFrAn6iQqRgVDRIKt8VA0tSxgyHMXRWCSkV0FzhqLgWq@ZUUYxrWOOmlYbBLgSS0BL/0wHtSowtYCFJuOGdhRkHKfw53joLUzST7JnOZogNyqGZtlNc6SggaZ8FfRT9I9evbyMxuRbPEBGNXd9M3wz1jX9hmh4okVMLFPONLaN4AqHGfOnGxto5AqtRkC1QIqn3uAQnNA/Ka2e0WfKkMy@ukxj9KqcK3bC9QYxppa45RibxeM0qoYHBYDWjKAtchHjMAXnIZVkEWoHfV27iY93Vp9VdE2rgpsSibFlnFHbha4c56JiEoySIEqe0Baxblkec8S5V@OcB3EwXCI7dAxtn84JJmulNNnrIC2o1Kz0OGS/a9ICOVU3NvKiNqZFzQYDtrgt5bUkoJ0jQnwtFegrjAAA1dCaP177gGtAIBaefGnatgkEAp7pGdAHG0NgskEs4V/fkphYf6cUIjyLT4VVAcjotFX4cvS6ixsFlpMFmpwp3ECf@vocO9WW6FbHyf8xqSUL18pytzhOgqITKynLnaIeX12Jx5ftFWXZxq7@8WOc07lZBk2ipsEQaQRA6nI3VgB@Bs2juGwXlo1NZblZTK9QDHiFQdo1RPjgJrXrZeMmufwYeuoE@Ax441WWXTIsmtI0/Qbyhy1kOZkAnrlGO4x0dwsmv2zF45gHbbmGGfiQPD@Nk8w@P03S9FFBaKPJdk80txmpGtTErZtrOAGFt6hoEOxpFOziMEfNB57YhF@dF7ZA9@AJf4nn5Rht0TXdsPovT4c8XLAIeRclm2/cjCu37AoEHClARHxNGLEYCJNf/CKiZ5msLG9lV7uX8WgmVYAfvbDOMuyz5fP0WoRFnhiGB0P25Mr1@V6ufcnMVjr7VlUrVkt7Wz2@OD7@ejSOnSvRyO7RK1lfA9B1tkHfh37WWXrBh33aJxJZSUqR5Ir@eD2ZfP36Nai8@KmUtJIPolVjFTVarSjrwqNXWl9fSWRzK4mTJ9Ea5AWKG1PS6dgps6wkO7f6brMJX6dDNykpEf5hW1uYHjjgnwm/3qhFztG22W4Py8aY@1uRIT72PRH32XdfvnyJjpf0Ye9ORPwIxyjQRfI1IxOhTKZT6b/806WbxPVxbfMvv99Lmkv4OMLHj26eoftUz3y2tPTZzs7aWgIIx93H3z3@Znt7e20vkTmuZLbW1NTS5l/8@dJSOr2ZTi5VXVevRisXX8vp1Jqs/eXvR2vHx99xXaw7/KwyHZz4m4OvzjIZdsHeweeixfCf3O@aIbeB7nrrHXaQoCwXSdhEo5nV6OmrKNbPu4iu65Ex/dWoaEtML22t/7efHL2NeJFSOvlyAE8v8jaSzUW4Exzwtuq/XUZKkU0Ey95ExslisQjO9f/27yF@6QvAgyHjTfgpZXxc2XGkpBYpyvtIKQsOPZ2GdP@f731PipRGkIlS6WCfpUvpFcEmeu6x/phcttcBBeM8oufWjp7Qq2U@OUpn0pvotk28gaYDw1EUMrqePmei8nRRhVhcHX@5B@uAG@vUiTAfdFLnzOco9jJC/AEMQjzC3cKD2IZ7vJyFe3luGCvr8bX0E7vwMvSZevnVf07woq/s0pPXe8nkZgn6efzk80/Oa6KRJdl6TnacJzj1V2CHwreAPyNHVR0Ah@85ear4EeSL5IqJGieR38b8EDZ5Y2GviKAkC5rTLwFXxs9f/V9/9dO/@gn9/ZS@/1mK@Nt41MplteR/gH/k0kC@Phev9jP2jH9sG/7h67@iD3qAyxYzk5HgUyrhD/2LN3LRc8ZPhJSCF4KYRFkIx3x5RelKkQ/JJMtjLV2WSuHywCcZvFIxeM7J8SxUukn5RHm24LMEf/QPn@AVf5fIR3gTyO3PEivd8bm7A5AilUilWh2N2BSSOzHi50RDptPEWy3cpVxKERWkVDx@AkzKBG/D5zx@z@cFfDWtJt6S2gRrRIr8yj8liUWu4VONqzc3Fe1VvFAQ/6DdFYI3/HAXZK16o6qbr0rxeIWyWCmJvG6q0TUnmnWesGqJF4B@tdqrTUAf36xsFp1d@mo1pJdafVWqbE7jIDTV0pMncSTtE0BQWq4yGFdAbdxs3pRuKps3N5ub8L9JvzfiCb43m7f@6TH5LICZhFex/s8rydJ5UjTKUhXeNeBp8NGS58jc8AS4SkWKXCPnsEqVjOMV1YqezVRVRg1kBYRXMq@vpFeTmdFn2XIaZICL4GlZTq6g4z32laDtbEgRHDds8OHDBnm8/vjt/4Hf84/f/lt4hazhLYQUWn@Lf4fv8O@th39nDfw7eYt/7Owd/p14@Pesjn/HLv6dvcW/7Tr@SZEiY6C7LW@luqnLlH6hX4DDYilQnTupjt6EboelTJYap8Ys1XP0JrhM@EuBy0q1WKrNUnbK1nUIBIfHUh66WvBow18LsAzgz0qlEHnqkkEqXezMyMI0Pd/XWOxcqrDoaxMULk3XUlrWqlUz2f7bSrRaiCTPz5NcC2XptQJZFL@5YaxWKz/fq9WS2BLOnzlHk/@jo1749c7/3pHz7MjpOfB/dHT07ByEWSn@JK4@gU@xFN8Uj61IqbB1nleRi31@jiQ3t85Lqyq6s3Fg0TT6xT/xM8EIz9LSuQSj9JcvrwrU4xauLgtXBXIEr9xREwACjDsgVkH01OAD8c5fJql3vYLPJeGlN3ReQaDv4o7ky6tz1CVh5BD8AznCr7@Cf@v/X//PXjClUo1BI7i@2VToE8O/WOz65vpG/JZiiiJelE34Qw94xyjXNyV0EtA1uCpKrBq7ueF@8KvENjnCEqaxWaLIE0AQG5EgTUqX/yi/2iemzT/nUVCZYEytiAXB8/NRKhUr1MEnWBUw3tPaUqxAu26W67geCONIPUYQmbVCQV/h7vRaulBYEy/ruUIhJ9zLirJx@1NKbenZbD69thaLFQopAQsjxoLvBBSmazQK2MgLkRhmlrd8JYXzknSXSFTOy48fK@L2ma1@P/b4sb6Rev8@8KrVmtagVkP/1ffv5ZqMG3SKGxl4T@XevwehE405A@W5w5eGFVVnn6VLlMKGM4BSrUMw05PpSZodwzU8b6C8s/oJGXeQunKM7H@nUs7gPPrzH3//@@fRIm7ZIN81HRFgKiyzuZldK5Wya@DO5qDg8jLfA6S04xt67GY5KfPiMnk5GhFBem49Rr43UQxnkU22VYKG6uKHXd9EqP7YWiam1Mdm7Bp8fD99Y4N7srWskotviL/iUoyVVpj4q1Qqq/G1lfWVJ1XUdW59UKgWro1iNJmM3hSvjTzOX90UGuKeCTzbZTx@vLoBxMylCudSrba3fbZdwysqcXUeukKGniShJVx57Q@iFZpszGxUK1iw6nk0mi88oWrXcxkWiRYEnBoFac9yG1T@iOtKVgsPeY4IqxThv/RdifSZvr4KPSx0sFKftkmtp1gTV5oHzGm1lsATao7VcVOAa3a7/s0cV86g27yymuaSFDk@3N4tnyXSm9Bfp/e3dxPp0xc7ER1fM5N3DGaRVfQ4KW/vHb2AGMeH5e3T8ucHX5VfHIO/K715Z5imYQ5N86o2HF69xdsbzJrZB9/Jp2Y2LNd488bo0wfGK1w0f/zZDz/@7H/6@Hs//vh7P/z4ez/9@bc//SF8/xC@P@bPH/@7jQz@/vzbf/YHH3/398DzP8P3P8H3T3/@7W99j3/p/c/g@19Cfn8mviE4/pUA16///Nuf/P7Pv/2N34bvvxTf3779/c0/nf/96Q8WfzHeT/7gbpgf/3v4/hHH5cP@@He5Hz5vwf8uh/uN3/74L/4D//8L8YfO3/v4L/4Mf8TLP/3tv/gvH7//H9Pp3F/8m48//PHHH/zk4w@@//EHP/r4g3@c/vhb/0ZPhX/@4ONP//i//8kf/fc/@V/o/w/p948e8v/xt//pX/@ff/1///WfiO@fwvc/gOtP//o/Aqf@7R//DP9/8sd/@59@hv//@7/62z/@X//21/81OX6HO/7ff/nv@O/ffP@Hf/ODf/433/92we8P7/z99gH@3/4D@Dw8nw/B85ByfarPt79Ufv4@1JikAjxAt2SwNGiwO2OT5i0@G@Wlz1iktIIfEMiVXDoXXwHlc2VjA6Rylfw3EYRJ0E5/@k8@/tavAfv/C0AGb/8zvME/f4GgH9EL@/rrqUAWp7kQNf711xgoRo9fh6F@BB7vk6CKp568B4ivKZh/WAAG6f5vBAZwTID5cNMZIBjc6sn9f/7tP/99CgjiovevTaFM@d5h6GUEf@8X9UfY7ielCUP/CEXHx5997@Pv/@OPP/udjz/7dewa1LWNxHYC@vW7J3sBMPMAOATMPgQOAHUcPcJof0lKg2NpEycoJT3@@jXkfglcMN5akTKr8CbpJXLr6IaIcXgjJKNRHH/hX1rbYPgCPiPyhSeLQ9BOHG9Pj0ujIoQRKF67ztBZyoHXCGcZioAXI/E4iVoORjJstENYIGYxfsJqK8URjxhHjxJhQLaR0OtE1tNyPFfcgwSLoz2GuBB5XHoNz9fFUq44KiG6D5QFwBHfgSQBCm91j49KH@C9SDgBXhrtfYCs5IrxeCkHPkUsZJxSS9QoTT1DhaOyxxmVG/0Zwy2XW0@gych6TuazIEBKJqDxNz6BRkAAh/Dz@IooDv37TvquYHyopxHRh/vx8C30pvgCAPCqKu7Ug6@qYm6eQPCIo4pTsvCIcwxAuTipUD5K8CB9JS7FqX7j9ALpQx4@7bOJogLRYXGWl5fBtVmSV@XaEQwgYaQ2uMi7njHAlUTSIvNMzm7I6I3bnviGzuVjGmmu7K3Arw7/5SXaxExlKaxIy1GcwIjyrEFaanzVWXMivBh@GelthYoQJ0D2GYTg98kTcAON6Dnxw2kG@o9LryISi1DdQ2NJ8F94aEXyDzUl8nhVlOKTd5x2FDE0LaElEuKp0ZM8NOHQKFQ8tWVSGBkf9NB6NdOzaywmKXQ/WQxrqGGSMiY9c9s7zggGHAlZTuhZXIOKiRmbs3waW6tUzqfg9xsnny9@0NfWJXjS@xDvSRM3dgHf4G3x2uYm1n/pWqVpJXSCypqVSiWx/M50qXRaPgPwsyOmp1Mag8HK9dp6ei2zlkmvZrOZ9bS@lt1Yy2ZyqyBZs6lMOq1vrK1t5DbWbwJqPQHhlMiv1DObpX906/M//KN5n/m@@JFKX7ORRjPpN1KpW@TbQJdxKV4@T8kFmuMiWi5XUgn8S6@uwi/kM6Fn1qtLS91rFYt9TnsPr3GzA2RVulax43sEHyY9ktgj8IIPpIGLkUxsHzk4KoitAnjdKd8uIOsZYGSoh3PgZI4OavT6@jr0lSJL3/2ux0olGHSoB/tSBNpgh/mL46rV1Doa3VLaHA5MCm0ztnfw1cHpwdFzbe/gFMYB37D0akqTIjc3N61gSYdeTXZ0dCSh8IPR3aqO8W8abDgcUmgd3m9GhtQPfwoht5ROq@lVdVVX9VX8v8eRxv@Hw6fhP42/EGs1LfETjl08yONPm21Im9xeR8mx8WR30b@BVQGqXvs302t1pznWXG8MQ7ym5fa7xrgYrXedxkW0MA1j4WU8eBSt6I37Jl0oQqcGz7g5/aViNLgeNrqVzmzkg@i@4xlU4lY6m56EvB2ag/Gp2aV7h7a7XYi3nk9nMzebwjZXaZOyVsIcXIv85W0YxN/gBtW80YJiXzf4xo68nM7k5JsnPbNpGQzi4wgQh@ZKDy@8wO3L@dR5KnY9N2o2Jd/4cc9TeHJqAVwW4CB7lC1pUxgBKdG6fAUaaRXvC6xUN33zICXpw4cPI9oKkz@wPbEnJr2WQ38moWR6DF3@Y507M9mJM4XOMzTl8hxaCYgWmx3i1nbPYWcO30K9YzYWQOx2DLo@cXfgwHj6l4fZMewLHrRncZsSQdBTA41Kuz3L6yyAeNHv4dlSc/APhqHcq0MGkZk4wA78DLqOMw9gnb04XlDKZ4EJKNw@QzagAPzk4POnZ6HnWXl796mUZTtHz/dmHhkBlGGH5f2z4HWdh/pRMwGKb8qHh7Ov4gH9VoEmUJZYZt136CxiyImaXKkWutfeTa4wMEfeemojs6U/fqwfHwIVl5OMndtDnK5I5fNku@KrZdaCAhV3IL6eZWssWyqXcqvAyBf5dP6DugmtvgbFrgN7QxsGUh8PXGCK8mjIXhie0SJRkr4q4KVg0ESxGYJG2ceWCJ1eNrvsLUvPcDfvhs6PplmuRCdE8eI@vKTTk9AYRdO5sunUXb07NNmwzxZ6wgO90AlypQPd9pXjA0h1w2Dw/dQPxA9PxgBB7/TweBrkdyukOwcct49YLZaSNE6ujVwmt7GaziVyG7m1jJ7NZBJ6OqGv59Y3oMNM6Tk9m8ts6Inc2sbqGvTqEJrZWJci0NFZrWQSVCddluGZB7R2A@@a2cRLexytU5IiXMSyd4oRA5YI3odMNiGOjLceuh4dWFixinJ6DU8TrULty7LBGiyyv7@b2t@X5R18wfWY3ZQsN/Elk0ul1ndk2aSQXdA80rLs8DgQBGAef0mldnZlecgRoOUqWe7gSzmL4zpZtvBld3t/H9N5gy9pjA9gFzyEv3T9l3UAs/FldZUGhrL8NkAHcNs8oTXKaRlfME0M2echuxAmy5/7@UmlAMMJh@MYnvpl3d6W5QP@sr2NIV9QwTM8q1/iyzZ9ZHkAL8CEstwGRxu7ElmugxNZUZYb4GqMDfDDe33QmpHtGbI85gRCEsnyiKCNxoUMwxfhj8k8ffrU6HhNs80/4wF/NiBrEGKNhuX9@uef19vt@mC8Xf78BEO@@OKp8WY8HNTbdRGtXoOPA3Eg5KI3nv1AHg9qNaM7N@RLCLFnQmrjmol5qxlvIU/i08ZEerUvIOQLCJkzaTzi2ODTA9A6fnZ68Nwx6hTifyiEnqN6XS4go6IWgZO82GYubJAFiZ7RGDgFfB8Vl1hUiSbGlWyqWiB/1lNAbUkVbjC8pdDdsaj6ozIzroyKqSoMa9fT4tSTIp@P0hlLTiz1tvSNTH7J2NLTa/FRHk2TO60oi6r6lqI/XnmnPI9tpVfX8vL51pYqV/TqVlrP5bPrr1aGshzL4@/W6nr@nZKKwggAf2KV9erWeiYUY309biTT@fX1WOEGqOFBF1UfematpihXpnERi2FuseNXYtdUVDamYlqFljJKjIo8U2wcK4yKeoHb1GCpW7iaaNRpiHKYY2wjRUZbqTzOsiuyvpGTIQPJpBKLoUhCIQLP1y/9RcDgEXJMOflHY3mVX/Cq57IxDQ/Q1JxWjS65Y6/DkDi8kV7iaTc66e5vSqURqZuXznA0hL0AaWNWHe@UJisTI2nELZExPkWmr29IUkkMBo759VoF8fr5010NxgfiDe1DafuoyDoDDa/A9qZCuO0i3@sMukjtqYlbTRu@3y4/g66VRzD4Q23YDzgU5580YddBO3tauFZrOE//nbOLs7PvqjdhtKcwMOIZwbM6BbKggafe0ZqW1WRGsQQuo6lQHpkRuyJa1EqlYq3YM3t9bwxDZr7vAErux34@7LEdxmHxBJ1/fqhW3AEipQo2GpQ08XWZjSIjqdREe1k7xZ3rYR61y5uCWTQHA2cgR/DY4ZZdHNqu0TKPzQGeeDs4Qn3AxLNljc7r8zJC7qKme6OWBsyelOLA5ZQMDjBRlq4xSyKgVkzdFML5Vgy1VI9Ne4Vev@Q2fSceSEDlO8AanDTXtOkbF5NuCq2i8ipW6AIRxSiU7wg3Cm8BYLDMlKa2w2Jba4WmssNqMfSC3hd/0iy7VqBbGZRTipKgVDHDRqxY@hKS46ld5POQX8EuF8U@jA95KkqL9S1RW62i1SQ446bQLlbQ7z3@bKqyXFXVyvsqDO0LUgmET2EcMYrusM7vUk3VYVSfLYzAT19fK3RYvVh/NSoMKB2Gm5yB6BDp3Xvl4699L7apZorcr0AR33dBqahpteJoUuGrxUoahtrp7BoOvbOr8NVhCJ7GbZuJdGojkdZBtwCdA@LDdx3e1@ALMKB6pHUcoCtdBQbUciI1Sml6Qjf1hJJ6bTVfxxIXiq8wxhKeU7aBC8EDmRH4mF7hacTi6ZWu0nSYsakSW4PoK1CJjEQHqJboIJoT0@hy8JjKVleU7rJC1D0b9suVaj5fHvW/A0GK@nYrG19Pxd/FYgVlKVZ0zbdETBSTRID@EvCYmHJg7rBXSS1BkaFJqjdQwd6yvp7OV4bLFVWHsqXetzflklyFarlhEvyFly1B8yqAny8Qua420bYmfn3Uu3EwyvSNdEGASH0hnxVZOZf9ExhKNLqejkZj0QJOtC2Bv5DvJIuj0DNEH@tbMmh7cl7eSEP4RKzfygEfsmd1KXIjkWoNg/fItXRzfbMZ3rr2JRuPjbjqvz5mrB1flliS9pNotQhbIpeqlWg6dLu43T7ZLgjo7V0pkqdNlZN9b@xcHKFnanLpU3exxDdLr/jzHLdvQbISmYWrsKqYgkivQqGboXcooHstcarybU3JzXiJJc8lWSaJxVfCc5kYzyv7EKHGzHav/cmL/DMcPzPFyPPGW6nGPjy3ute5VZWPwRUW@cDiSY125tWSHyLQJd4Qrf1dmF@@TmeA@rbje8Bo2wOZDj1oJiPjxJ/5mvVPN16tv8q9evbi6MXRPnuSyufyuZmZ//MniYQe1aOb7Alo8NZJGYZu75mT0T/YX/CtqpFCJN@Prq5FV2ejFiOj4pq/1UHRSyVV30yzLeBVlgep29Kzaup9iTNeiQKyaQj5@Gu/vTbazMF7GjTlPNA0E0@XSvpKOhbpf/z23@JRy@vyV9uHLIqGL/7uz38/vf53f/6vaF09elNAv/TqegQg0aln1yPX1/3r6xv48LBMpBrheVpbj4Gb7/nQI6Wk8NbX9VjEVfkbZDcTcd8LSzhKOpWDsN0j/iZngZqRjYgUyT17/Z6xTRhXl5rttpUmVzJ5ayllGYek8M8@4NTpB3XpdbG0nAQGwHngDYzgT/WtlEqlFVyjYdFSHI8NpzO0VFS5KVSBqPjBsdmKTX@mu4J/@P6Ke6y4Lrz7wfCK0/SbJsuUdAbjuWTy46/9Vjqd/bs//83z2Pva@9p3QcxubGxk9XTkF5CPO87y@QMymufBU3noCAZybMH1jlpDliI0f8Y4vD@sw4EcnmTndoDwTbpEBYNIXAM6GqBFKwS2gieSEqRP0/HlWEGSAsWT9OVBu5EgHGwFbelC25GupUcYBB0tK4Jskh5NUIFHDw0INWpudzjokwKoUDy9mmCPIQqk8AhNTizRSSoh4FS9wJIrt6PyLHPrM6SjsJ7pumh1CuSv9AiiHAKX0qU8rG/gaTyEtGwQqBqCUD4poFmBtKuQdpdHqJGvQqXnAAnGc8cj2aBUS4/waBEp3dDxMmsTAAosJj0CAkAZFIHYqrJNthpj11Y8XpgYqbrBXXFoocDwz/pIGA2xNfGAmx@5gHAWN0QxHKBxJiZquGGGPX0kHAdfwSnCcACj0xtqLHSc78GoABcd61aoaOzx40muiqDHxBiVCPGjjS40rDWxKHQrAUDmj6M@a@blBLPjcazsR9NsBxSPU3aB61RyTIBaeOgKX28kCf4fzLTIkTNVRQEFLICoL94qGkAyiIxk53XYQCtjeno9xoLMNyDvDcoUGSsJBofno880shnU4Fm8kX4R8Y1RSnh5dmg4I/h29rAXA7k0xOuJ8CQ7FwbiGBe/uAKF04Hnxw5iQVGsLkG3rAEMDWg1yjd7oqzqMYzWCnwoH7QbLr3GcKNaJoYPioXQaBzDQEMTIp0lmvEmC11u37HJMgWd8sXtfGQvzJW4HQ6e7aF9ZZCNKZ4K7X4L5Ygb7kLOJ7tSNjee5fK4uPJVH8AA16dNgpltjUywpDeYwo3BoQkAO0AXo0iUYRgOGkjjetfsQZZOTZOhdQQ3n0y2La8zrJM5hGcW8FVn34Juw3aT4iKk5JV1YSXP0Jie6rRAGRXH7yLsK6NrBZaJhM0BMizWtS5MPkpVps5PuiydTYC6lwDKTr5A2DzOw@IZyRQEJzgUfNfhsc6duUQo7pIyjt1@rupLSi1GagEZjRngZUeXhh2iL33eS2Js6Y5d/3A0ndaDdy0QudAy@QmpKB6RCo7uSeIUd5FOGGs4Qd5XQJ3yz/ShE1RM8xIgVF3CPgaEZsM/bIitGEr7iDoAanvQstB6iDfI4yncItrVUhrQ9ISAt9lnbDVNV8jzc@niGDngwKovTmOHMIiK5XC9JlSMxqcWQK5A6@w1ISyCxnQ4@2F8n7vRTZZ0JuzNlgQ67HQorSLjzcJ/yYResHVwu2hQ9CUIzEIO5@RkSZHjgDYux2SOOog/G51zu0SyJM9uY0owxCBIDVhQVdgxXG5XU5j@uLq60sj6zHBgaaaLBk9dvMQt2W9boI06Sc/s9cVdFRZeNCQuUZu4VG7wGO/82xrRVXsbj8f8KUktPA/7dmgNTCXacqPYB16CrOy3e3S0Hw/du8Q3@xYZAG4otEDqCjZLVxPXPpvlkc3UXPQGkTCGaEaJcaKRAGSJeuMi0bpqFkTAJbU7QA6VZfqeaBhu4L/0XN9l9VsBhOPRxlr/vd69aDhdB1UPmc@dTpLmJfQhx/6reO9bI4hkm1dsezAwxgqFxxAa@VQZk3bDxtC7Uwg4oTdh19x@kjWqjKtT0UdBdOi7/LEHG@DBfun6bqTcbBWGj3j4CMJHPHw0SdRPtjKqcs0LvW6wOMjcaKfHh0Q0Yx/mhlvdmoQQZtCLmc5RIOR4yu8Gvo0ixfbpzd@gHos@YwBPkLE7Ba3sVc6rtmterVTjyTbwtEyEgBoH1JUq0fSqGbiR@t3Lbt9xp7xsNGMDnY/IN3o1OoIbOK9gGYMKIsbg9LLQ2km7p/HJH97viwIDBlS3IBA1gG1PsWKFwM4oBQLjVOQJjXnGKiIzVVKyRJDwA62Ik54TNoyoGkKE/kGRIJsQwvyWI8xZCyHwcoA3f/qwKt23QAZTo9UoUHKmqXCRUqBKCuVKVf1sAtlRKy3OFsUPh6qozASFinkj6j@c/aVPzn4L2sX83BPD8n6hIIWbijlC45CmaC5EVVYqhuoVcpBcMbrmADqoMldDRacMyawk/dEETweLwI2aKqHKb8R4/dCZBdmW8wErjItFKOK4yJslbxc@STnBg2iuiDb2GUHE5wIEcKTmRjNFtFE42qhY5IKDjRZEuwplckSZHPEoHHq0IJNVEQ0GSYHZTKyeKlpLA4VKBnw67y3RMqjMXOMSzb@yN2jdBAZPfpoTmUNcIHgINWnks0Z1buqVUKZDQmsGATLiLQRNfntGXpoVeLoavAUyipPSl1H8TbABlxXAYCSCC9yClRIwGQ11Qa@X49QPQNuV4xVJ1nGDEv2l@FdO@J7@V7/tmZqG1Kc9U4mZv38QzypSNtRAQ0qGnlpDgYwDlm0y6AFqyZXDlDnKM/gn/etRk/WuU0/2DNxLgfcoB5emxvzxAJnse9J3PMNz1tbyfBBkEX@9EOAsZLmejwGstu3AUCNsIc/iFv3sKBoubDht23LNBF7TylVwkxb4uaFxKaz3CqfjSpKY9ePDUkTNGQhV11oNr/ip1RTX7LZi@cD8JL5qyIfRqITjWXCF4oMcEkiP@oqDd1R7sftxovlIEe3MalwoR30RGIVEthkIqwbo8xDaAVWFuc5kJEh23VA1rnsKmVnvOD2nDeod2mzE2DPoDya4MUNGv095STADh6j5kJFNag5KI2HERNQvPzkq@zKtGLEgfnoawRQxEmwwS2Ok7GBOcrWFyfFofnqnn57f03B@T@/OL42qZ/PMh9pFHvhpSa8qEwwAOMnG6v3ZSAgTybeyM5WVwBsVKB7hwVls0l6lJuZ0G0C3BbjWAv5IBG8uGW4RGf9qEf3vrkA/evmh1WfgjWenY5A3PdwSp9BFA66//qcA@EEMZc/t5ALW3ntgWgALegTbR10B9FUSXDZaBYKG2YdhtCsHSx4C8T08jzuPbvE9bUcq8sA5eRpcJthFenEV7dWaZtcYm01FQCZCeP0Sn8DIjOTVwwqOgo6EnsMHdQp0UrGwSWEkOgfKL2AZI3EZMih9C4aDWAH30Mw35fBgMf0w/JZoxim7Ip99BoU/Go2Q7XEyFd8f98fcmmKXX8ch5Cjvf3hN4snN@wkCdBBbFxKTZGN3ic8TJSjSA3qEAFabLjLZTfK7LafXv12Hn0ai@0sKlRuKVPRrecre86Iat@6q8RBX@DzJ13MexpL3Md2DeS7EahzZRITtfloXcgsz7nloNJQwRu5zZ4059i2ZgH4072Yv6FVqcwRqEJMknWfRuJr0i5iEQ@ADeOIE0lfwRIRt06txhvLLhnNU4uIWRiE9ox/SWoQPaOOAJURF36o/ZSMEJfluAL@@CdJsLEyzcSvNxlSaQQuYTjIEJDWmkhS1gNVzVxV0zZa3QDpjEA6S4XGX2IaP7RgDnJa4jlrRvJVg0ctoHgRy1IzmywoI5Wgzmt8jhxvNn5LjIpr/EhyTthV9H837zQIBBvBKjifoL0Q4vjei@V0ldiN5ePGCn64WzQd1CjBb/JUoAqTAcoPWiEtmtiOK6Q1M6NhIqUww5Bg3geMkmnBJ0DcF/9zCOr8JBAJxznKFgFmc6VOdRqjH4OlAt@Hb3pzTkvOiNy8f7dOeoYkJewiPw2AuHIfQgxoeiU4LI54xDKUVCnhCBlFu5ufniOnT9xw8IDsideBQquTp9Il6GukDTYXCKwBcjU2bzxfx/fqaRsEr8GH5xMiL8nkrO35ylCNcY43NyRYS9XX0jkJhXc/cDcFrP1xDNHc9DYQ3BPogvJYIbUimgw5Hi22YWN/pTzMJheJ2Pisch2bfeKNE7p2JRlJBtMwFweQtSoaCIdz4Y3cVJxQPszYlgjCwkqryVhb0CySLMWgi60KaKm98kIWQzIEWbjYuTGTbPeEkOC5uEtRXLOqG/Lg8SZJc02ISImtogmJoeDz1YPBaRsMUnzZ89WOOcFJFQQShmEEqXL46n6C/O1x/9xVqnwgzCcxTrOd3pbfV6zt72ZmcdyfJ3q5ADEywvdhc5ShIYUJyGB2ENPO7eO2Wio9bOLiSzxMNsM9o@z7ZgjHBPXSbHVtwXKglDC6nPS/S4HmRXkyo2xpJ91LzlRYNUxJ4eMGDnE6KdndeecHnVTGG0ES20f3kCh5MV3C48hAfFWAwQ3LeyvFIIa5tTdo2GTZFHxSpep5xQU7Ln0E1TzxB3NNSbLAMCx5HtZO9o@eH30Cnu76@HhN99HiSP2y1OKka9OMcM206DvqDOcOWdAINe@PiNc67042bS@e2fEuWcGENygBeaOKzn2jjMSHLQvJ8pu1CPA4boqjAdTFpBsaUVEJVx8Au2xJ09YAgpqesGAKJr94CvRM0WovhnCxwB96NVqtR91Wr4WakWk30Ylg1/gp37BeRpeTQHdBVh9zs8JXETb@wvSP28un2GTt7Wmb7L3a/ZN8cvWAvt5@f4QHa4xc7hwe7DL7l56dlNplRwA9exYADSqDrntkwe3UQ2elUao0bldl1@mMud5TdGPc/NXrsqdMwcT1q0zV6Tzr8RbNNr8RjlWE4Oha3dvfx0JTn8WvMGoCOlJsmnVLDbfsMYOswpu3hmLfnNK2WBbASjn37lun6Z6ZY14IaBHnrn4xMcCUJr4WgrUB0JRjd5obXgQE8LtIAGsOdXD9nuTyC2dSEzZzJ55MpeFY@eXbKtp/vsd2j53sHZwdHz0/Z/tEJvB5/c/D8c6DnwenZycHOCwwiwGdHewf7B7vb5MEzkNIYHpGm@93uyoKG4ESVxgUucdPVpcFbeNYZwECDZ1cGnddzWXRoo/SxjK71zmxGCxJeGMPPCNKaAAuua2PmW1zK9Nd8aT@B/MKlK0@WU2yTUoPGUoL2VhDNFbo9ND6NCw@9McOrb8wCnVxWyD25Uoc25TQtk8m7uOcE5775AWdqyz5qSGgJcCMqfwNKkZEl92g0sUkoS5Bao@ugES6eGt8UKF4w6hN/60hBIoqJvS@IFE8DHNg4H6QXAg/ge/BIi2S9AQdgq4EHB2Br3ANV0QPcC8IyAmLoHQ1RPLMs93jT6@/T@i9bDzx2DBrF5kSeeL1RlRpsciWy1et3yRY/n@WhK3YMt2FZFMUleLRl3@3699zVTWB5kIniViLcqwaQMgibFi41iG1s9pAaNoQCN@C@H6PluUwpxjR2hpt9TNvilxy0u4bNtzRNtuIQ77Ecmq8oit3WVnB7QJPfR04MiDd6TOcjiLcntELzofEg5s6tFA2x55FuoPG3lN2XgZ1bGfhl0AAidWqk06Ceik5nIhqnJVhZcR3gSJy3/RCGB3ZuDhvmVAT/FsI31rt3MUHkxNQ4yd93SLmDKsILGxN8zbLlDKCNk1jt4WkVlIKNjtP3LF6HynQJJndIATR2bJDa62JpKjW6N3ImRduxQ4nWgYsXpFoHpnxIqsTxfJE8EF9@Ww8usaJ9dJgdo@5cmqG1swQuIl2ZOP0CijC/gA97G7pQVeif0kR2fKBLEXPF0t7OufrhdQJN8HOxwK@d8jcR8ksUe5gWNA9a56MNiAPUu0RL8@9xcId1jC321Alpia3cRwbjwI4F47ontUIQxrcP3/bHoyOz/uT5/n2Rx1JRMnGJPHQ7ykS6JVjFTzJBcapM7PUIyU7ILMh6xfdJEM5AXj/BcyJYCwWgiI1yhK4/nb4/QYgQv3T1YQski7ghSVR3gD/GSrR1wlck6aOE6yP5Stkpxkux5GTnCAuRU/FFdMLHjBcoTfafUH91C93e3ehAfj8cXe7O3PHu4ZOw7d2J7ZPypsYX4@LdUgjXw9F@uAMt79x@KbRQ9sRixLyTvI0t4PSAORPLkWB37N0pvr5Vd9T2AA32vTiDEiANpTa0aYnat5Sp8AixMJqJQnR6tlc@OWEyH59AXJB7OGRoCjGIuJf49RJ896xlk7DTAqUpGCwHypPvM7V1LTjycUdjnku8BaJC6CAJQY9AWExf5khST/QspELQbnoSiD7lpnN37csgtyIQ36BpVBBekYkaFhRQmlvMCO98LDe8qVvQLcF14/CefNoxzftuvJZpMA4jCm/@Mdp4UmR@/b3k@nHeT4crWObbIRW4CZo03kyqsVNIuA@AmjZdg3dUi1@luGmeK9gRn3a4wys1rWH//RmKGIkr4VwXDol1oRyLrHH9eNlXc2jnIXYDBm7pFIF8hzIE@CKefDbDFRqbdHrKdBcESiZeGPQkzBUQvXpTCO4YVSb9ZDFQyMNtbZlyU/FzWcXZWYG7sBjoM9zbnJ0VD7NJgbS9Myn1V5MU7yWmUvJpPrcwfiBgzmYyq/fhni2FH139@@Lmfcis/PR6fRjfT1C6Y5em94FzD54n/PAJA9xBOr5V3m8wMxFB1ZnTp0yVnTqjcP4gL3xeCDKD5mcbHbweaTrVGBvN5G0@dt4jhbETyK0yhJpwUFDeam5R/@bu5FAg35ve0qenxxsbAuEewZtfBIfrQmZSQl54THTazxwMbALjx5J6Dh4fo9NId56Zo0NzfEMrLwwG0jJbuAAtcciIb6tN@FMMlAjNKmp4nRpO6hVmZ/VUvRAu4f7BYZmtkF201tQUpDyQYyGRs2TZd2WARC9NR2CvQUfxPnPz8IU8JHyUQCY6lKcQbWL35o0oAspyhaz6i22fQqTqs5XechuGjTY7EjLdRPwYItLka/loPzZvQj1VmIoPmXP7tgKxErKqyRQV/HAeFzFNo@C1if6hfkpCq/Zig@Qdl68aST2Xym5IVDo74SV6lY1qYqVRlBn0uYbdc4eDq@ZF2@lctliX9d/UR43xu7eMZdYYHvFNP@YWIPVsEU@3Kgzvi8qxjRQxrMjgFlmzPJcZ08iMH64ns8nwu7CExgnhQ2PlPJ6AmOFSttLzuRBPynnFXiVbLdrFVKFXsasFPKvnxYteXI8r6PEYOk8QLXxBvuJVsSv9RXi21bQv2WBYH8MoKTj7wejsB/bvOMMl9mzTfDltM5Ye4WY1PEOi2eaVElwsjZwpof4jPaJDPDqe9qbpYpxtaVqQA6B@ApRVd0S/45j0KKUN@55DISIhFVmIvbfeS4/8U0cpmjAAkIpV9bOzSXgmMAqu@3DfMd8NrepcG9PxqGMshKKCMUnayeeyjEcAMaPi6FWlKrmaaTQ6mAm8QvA9RWObm/xu8RsIpkk63KlhDOjgQ6qKTlzfgEefFhMwCVLMXTq@IUHx8V1HB/ehKSiPzrvQRneJFEEMwW3c7JqOI1H8TSAAJ/wjrlJpYgZTKFagJ/KjfjR3gPbjpsf1uIqApyB5pTzCwiJunl5xgpx2fBONMFlBJvB/dIXk5LSCjyiBqtPbrWIE8DEOTiShZWjx5iItqUopqISP7iSaEoqm@tF84BApHt1LDZzIgtHPMxOaz5jtmt0uZJrT4tGEHOik47gi/XiQvlvBNKtB5nm4eitcnQrXeDjP1ARKg/57ApQPA8mR6wncDZMnYIlbaRUZ6SYa1HRDA41jAlu4C9bVPKdmTYBLQVVyrgwCNqcC1FDIqzm1z0OWpuIEDB6EV3i44O@0qPkgl1OwT6bTx6ckKsikvbFiK8kMl2q21d3inVMQgmwmM7ysnkfH@ia2441SHJkU4gQUNJzGp2ZbKk6wxHVf4lCbkUubT2RNKBNbymw2@KHDWw1rThsJUYnSjBPhRnS@ENKh4KUQCsKJjMb8llvyI49F5HEILUIt@cnyQ4u3GjgUbbaJF/EY43v88Rv7dOZ8uMj8wEc85yNeeH4YeZpAJHSX5PlkmpYmeOyDe4pC3dGLTNIez2KcLySehyZ5gzRNfmS6hbPcS4GcCAsKX1LconsQIig9AdB99l1UhRh4I/0iuSJ9boAK3e@aI7aNowiDTlNJU@fRPdP1XLRjhCYsYXje73dxUZEUuys68Sxsc6QzuJoywRhaRtOkA9y4w@ET6BLnxyGSxo4Q8xXu/5gEuMN2m99Mz9CyEohWnFCxPE3atsd8vgLazGqanwo32dDli6IwmG@HM8FrjrcepDRd665JoIu5oOVIvKgt3r7FdDkeC0ErW9Cl5SXpO0OrcbH7OS7XruupVT1Eskux2pvSVtcmB6WASH5AOgXqakZfk6TQ0m@DL/2qiDDBDrGj/wp407zE63OlbegxCNAF5dQ1B5dmU5OkEzNY40W8yMq48IjHpp3hoMHnbkC3wmt38bSvm@CrXcBh@MT@ma8GN2gpLCHhmtRkMRmq@tJqIgH9AyUtBxd/aT0CT/VzemCknukBUVZibDpLtLQs8kK6Sw/nmYAaaJYktPQQkMF2PKsBNUMTVVIXUPFVjkli/JLwUE4gvUbXwEO@2rwM4OmXCQX8DPgrRXflQRJr4p@UByYK5i@hG37NJEH6OdRWoLmbAwuk74TAVCsULZR3qOCzpwen7PRo/@zl9kmZgfv45Oirg73yHtv5hpawcR2cbLyyp0eHIF2CxXK@KH4EHvL2KcSUKUDafv4NK399fFI@PWVHJ@zg2fHhAWAD9Cfbz88OyqcJdvB89/DFHi2uAwb2/OiMHR48OzgDsLOjBKXqR5Mm8djRPntWPtl9Cq/bOweHB2ffUIr7B2fPMTFctN9mx9snZwe7Lw63T9jxi5Pjo9Myw4JJewenu4fbB8/KexqkD2my8lfl52fs9On24eFMQY9ePi@fMNoDECrlThlyub0DQ1VMicq5d3BS3j3DAk1cu0A8yOBhgp0el3cP0FH@ugzF2T75JiGQnpa/8wKAIJDtbT/b/hwKJyn3UAXqZffFSfkZZhoocfpi5/Ts4OzFWZl9fnS0R7Q@LZ98dbBbPi0w6fDolAj24rScYHh/ESUNOIBaEA7unRenB0S3g@dn0Ge8OMbtDDGo5JdAGMjlNkTdIwLjLgcsLRDp6OQbxIp0oApIsJdPy@B/gjQlam0jFXDDxO5ZGAwSBCKehYvJnpc/Pzz4vPx8t4zBR4jm5cFpOQYVdnCKAAe43@IbYB1I9AWVGusJ8sWdwKySz7kJqk52sM@29746wJwLaOCA0wPBLUS23aeC5tCWk1JossRycG7A6IUnUFq3vS7JhvftmZf5czGBgaPdo70yaHzcfpY88X8BnU5uxvBROAw6miAQXqcMzDTN@rBds@yWg0dF/7/2nm27bSPJZ/Mr2qAtAhLvupuCYsmOJ87Gk9nYk8tKCgWSIIWEIjEEaJF2tOfsPuwP7Afsp@zDfsp8yG7dutGAKEu5bJKZMzknFgj0pbq6urqquqraVGP7xmUyquKtDh5o5@q09IGLPcSMQhXK5W73y6Mu6Lmvu12vep@aOTDuqiFG7g@V8mSMmMsdFW@07zx5wmg/yCHqcE2OMckND48XsCQjf40d24LL0FONxiCUahiDjw1rC1HChyIXeFACnJFCGfGeg6xLMkDQ70iogSq6uvl6v4tWUPR7pELTBP6Z/JD94L3BegHMma1ajQbqsARG9C7U3XAnlNmA/pHEAtGQuqwnYfj9yG3a3aHKXx9NpwPX83QdKpuCGjhyvTuq98JRoXqtWJ@ApUNlSRCfaLWbJBhzuiwoUzIv9RmNzMV/uin98TQ0nLoBbaLUFZmixTbprnF19DeqKslQgcETNMko8r06@vrlV6jMNdtbncL7T8x7XlvoDYjZZGG/O6F6Z/TnkzMuAAuMUmoASiJJdNFoWHW0N4kpfAUFL7AQZdqnrfoipG0dUAJy7DwY233iZjyLFjb0wIb/8MXRq@M/v3gBnBOh3drb3t3plEySrK@r/Pcb7IdydFKOsBi2cRDT6JO1Sp6B3EMrxcqJnZE/EXCjgQUx67ieNHqJ6RqMV0beTwn5GA43wUs/JuiA54SIB0dRHo2HJU2vK1emEICbG6qHo7kMFiThByAqEQ2Iq8p4SbO2wH@wbbP89RI3AxICEhKjHLNAuaBcEN9zXmhHUNJtKM0OFqk7mo456ZrBAVm6yDsWY2fpl9C2NYsJOyrieqVpp5oAxMMiFEp7TUx4Zf@J0oWInZdyfcGbr4Xe4PEbSUdHyemCJD1KXwMaX5iaaI7ObM4y6BNp@ezQhylaWzM9HSg05nsCFK09sRqb/B7WaiBQztBl0FeFhjsmHUixS/JvfVrx1HumVMzBge10hGLlN1DuquFIKx2dBkR@6@QSitsyuUoYa1emj5Iu8o1JR6HRmUPTz8IHtf8b4mRF@wegcELrGbaslH33wiS1yrgC7ZWQEl3p8wTrECPDpv3qm6yZa3tiLszA5JBmwdEzgAKZnaV@8Q0lKRy6KxCARI52DXv9GoeziwA0p6eOJ9XxOGTSv4xdJXuF3iputHtWJZmrqg9Q8IenPDY0Wd19BhXVU/aRS0XhAi7WW6rHicNtbLQ8nbujsU5GD7PKiTQv2BG1SE5NWVp68UuaJGuXGZhsRyCKXt96IreurCyWOYYvp1pex85uaQ9Y0AZ9HiKgK8eNHvjsipvPlsiJ0N9QBjtMro06M25Fkm6uR06X4xDbeTwgywjeRppe4XYx5tYpzV7WmnIfk1MIdpJ5GGY5ApH5enXAOm2yVwZ6MlMivRro/zzh/PIhm7h0iTon8xAI7dD4unoVLBHm8f3G7WSdbyBaD/P9v5xQ6sF@yjtlPE1Ic4deUNN/nGQY0W44sA9lWBL/S0fTaHRVixbwh/qqych1EkfQGSjB5Cqh//pWhYDyS@ZPSJVzOjFGpCe8kfmPtfiCT7x2zdM3@CR2Zh8GBcDBGzxOFTEIQUa5CY/wbq42gg9zw30VhbOBbZaD3XQQxGgBIvF7OqFtV1uvJINcP0iTcAlSaL8RLRrURtf9dHox6T6bjoNRNI0C0BUwhfaCFyA@LukR83@OZtOrhC5foQ8Dq9BgmT1zBhPO6IW/zdFYx8rylKRh7Non4ulseXTBiQjIeItuZsrwTEqiGhfTbZk6W9tZpVI@wpE8vlpe59a6m61VlfnwGBuQZXVYOKznKMWUQl@s8MbOjQK9DxWwYOypmgq8W3zCchDvA4roJCAHsQbmxgm4PQjUDm6F@GSwqA4ond0MU/mEz0O8viRx6XU1wEskgdN/hIfST1Rrr2lVZUP@AlPa4cPydnS3d39j6AGAnwF@a3MVtawiBEroO9T5fBKWmSUvJcBirjyroiYASvJ0Fo1AsR3nGu0uiq3mPy9vwwY5mcDWLBnbblAlrkgXhG@8yMvtAsvpLj31ww@qoioeZYbAHfEodZu3E2x4l4cmLX48R2TjDTKmZ9KyawF9G6r6gCW8QbDgwGmDzFl4714x7fZ9Z62AQH@VU5N1Q4Dr6P2SYhxE5sGTlekMmLFTwJ54G1SSdBpX7om9W3nHyiRfq3Dd97w7XU2Z2PzFRnt9QKj1l/i47JSK8BSIJo8xcmoCGkIVip4NmReRuPC7uN787vIOPNyGs8xFx2wqZr4HvPZxU3yLPqN6ozFLimDHfJcd8/6kCwPv3s5BpE0W8bvEMbrIMrpLfrSaKqDJYOn@GCLqE9gL@BgA5rDfAeDOnp9bkVr0x9LZM/WnXL5ExCem@sawQOBL8RDP/zERGR@RGCbFWc3DJ5jYlU6TWrUe5qvFD9wgBquEtcwWwlbEbLIKdET55IduFx1WWsiJ4OnQPmQ3aeINwiiPuxgY5NC9u6y1zjrc0sK0BLIslfpQSzqiGX6edBfUyg1UwBJfgQozohu86eL@o/q5Y4Fy0ALXps/iS9qs4mA8tQHQwD/2p@4CZeCsK6mZW1H5hdAl1gBrAdSQ0Thk7Qmlv2jGFI8H7LKMQLTn1y7@2ZAamAB6p2mwjVUWgyUW8QTdvNo8VTvkKhlB8W9EvyxFFnVJXYIGQoYY6vstaAEzZBL0aJim5C425eUAlTmCin4LlyW8pASbmUvhiu@IVCmwtW2VaK4qsW@3UVvZCAgWq8tkgIDMsrpI1gpsdCthsUrsrh5PVgIEYk37jHGYCpmVPA7NzDEC4ZGgNRzlpKWqTaFg@ri17eU@Gvqmr/tN62uz@BXwYyA8qbWKX/eaua@5btvtfNVcTcCHZ/ea@wio8GyADVf4ef9R8IOdPdu4JVpKRk7KEFfgCapSV6i31b9L1AGF/WoZQ7dnxx5r9avLl3Lk8nt/OJe3kkzxnZ8/WO0bqQGR5PKU@ExHU7isD5LA6uBOj6NCRVencjMR8FqlnQ7Vl29evMjlFe0ttavLZTjbbjabSMM9O4269uJF@0U0beRLN4bz8bgRX306@7LXINaPl3OPk@kTrUCHMCOwJpL6dDbiqwQQBiiKpWsSKYmq/nw4tHP24yEZzh3MGpeUcHtF@09k3C6@fEMGHmpS9tdzHCCO71yZxXcVsJwpreiTEKiNTqlvHX2AA@jBF0P0BDaHJdQY8mXtTwPblucfvscNBK/CoMmiRLje@8xB1vkkHI@nVfXVdDYeYCj6g@tihRcv7ApNLoKHXBQ@Ok8o4WlVhW@jsRW4ikVsUsfm9L6kLybQGcYxy/oX4ejjRew6J986sKvAkDdwmBuY6biqnJHjSdrxezTLdAhg36v0ZRC7fcJTsTDs9LKAsyeAaLNVXan65Ip4dMWI4Ozu0ojU1eDWKRsADN0jUUBnRafppZHcUtwg1zldtIaIwya3ITBhUo/71cBYpt@OK75Nh8P7MUVKKM8T@6szRLJI0wqU5Qf4xHzM/1SDZf2ikLGC5Ru89uEm38EKXaxQKj3u@3@5co@OjtSjeGNDHR0dw0Otpo6Oj9RzfHF8rJ7D72P8vea3t7c7zHOfe@/h5bF@ea2OoQ0ycG70L2bP4Sd88zEwCf2FcYofNfxH1c6jrn9w2EkaJ0fHGDcOT3/9t//467//Z@NIfvwX/jimHyffmkL1er3xqP/@0dp1B3@fPD@rPOqdPIrPKqMOUhmy@z/PkmAcWA6M9X7pjiCdwTjq3Ra4Yzw4ooS8BdFjz4V/fB80sB9@4KfTNHucZY@YljOrHozji4CqK2rh0K8cVdbW4OnAr/xLhWwn8j4w79/Be@UhL6e4fUItXj2jjl4/e/nSznyNXJ@k92GIaVrwZkQ5NokmSQSDOi/rO@dqJ6peV2c1dW7AQ1eDLhfMg8hqJgPzrwKkHh35hdD5qagNeDBKpm@2yPM5yWUyIvlOm875/q1ANJXHgyd8qENtbADDw/IddpeW0EscPoCLpzB@7aS1s31WK5fLJXMnV7dPbI56i6kvc0eTPsalMxiOBIphycDY6Y40H3EBDSIyymW6sWmtzzeLuRNUrUljYoW7XLHkebQ30UBKhs2xhZvj@VHGQoWPbsFSyZwCAVA2WN73SAkAoAivA2Jcim/ZTeKwHw2X5tgdL0XIeoe9EqO21tXwRtCWcmY9R8b1cJg1CAhBKYDSxWCjxQYZeVMoGxG34zHq3yBu3CSqc8k/rbZogo1TSjwdL0dj6Mwld57kCrgTYN6TyRpPdDQX9sA1e@EQr3fnFc0TlrmTIty9EE0Rkz4omAO8omiMaaFY4OMjSEqICOsBJRy5omyI0QjueMJOLNMhPMKGj4FcfB0bkeEGbqlCUKjUonKsrzgTPrAee56KuSRiFX5nB8BEHmSCJH1Y7lrLHQXGntTEtwdCaTHeLoeKtKSn9GQlObRWzAEsSJWXeECGh2OAFCxZp@usgDUs1fl4cm7Gz0dqCd6IR@dnfOEcddPmM3LgWKYbHbFN3bE7usPGVbr8ahKkgt54miRRD5CVLvU0URY@9l@fQaunlRJ3JtSCB3WIYHy1HpsVZY9Pk1K4iClEnOF9gKbdiaaCXEE8VsQzMT4bLudOiifTSY1Ybi9Moz478XHvDzUvjvGYlrz3CbDbOwLlgQ8q9QRTD6c6wY2cUdJUZ@0QntBfHtf/hRG9A8KZmHmFRUvsAgBkiMPMzmmGpKxFQwnUQB4pAiO5IAsGH@QIcxyOojRXpypJANjzmUdxrVGPi/wcAbaxW8As@urTquxZ@8y54Fu7ByDj1d@A0e55En@7ivb0YHBX47sPTU0eEoV07d2kD8OPNDg21LCCAX24fKv5GaLNFfc6ymOG2SQHeVJV2Sx8sAdqXEBkfrFOMSbUgHCLIk5qJ4CNdgEbwE4LyyDjws1c8xYBI3HbOznxqAJ6ebpYJLjBvDW9aEiRCK5LJqrk/f93v7mp7M0wRBYWH5RCOoA9OnNzMKkcik2uXIFXoRbUJT8bsMbZHJOisfuE7CiYRSXiRWp1auAodKWHLjNcI0kpphQd8POkYs9loaoeb1b7LF@7VuGoovc6tsi1JJ3Yk5Aj@fqAN/PWzrZul4OG6OiNfl3r6CYJDjI@E3p2BOW0vQZDRA96YdA1P2ZyrleRhtbhNZfXYxbJAoTLXOPUFh3RSDnbE2UFkthX4WieTl@mv7xMT@mN5azPvKQbP0EuCEAMFhEh8BryBI/oAev9UmoB8oEIGAH7UAVJCM@lEkseomE6r5LR8XThNqunzqlTbe3sew7pyUYOK/cT0IzK/ZATduGtgaJ7UmJAsmu/DZmFz3rRYBBOdDpQqCq9mU9dafYEzfnvDbtL@JJVh5h46Fi8PKnBJNILwTU9x7NgdBnQ4x@nb2bB8iVsQvTz8wnP52ts7wvYjPBaIPryBa/RowGIGs416skZTdxriBSyFIDk009JNOBkcJa4sAIB4Q0EcJ9m/El@sBYa7PGz7cJIz7RvwqSes4SSsCPvOR@cnJf4ztlLvBS1y@@ANl3rUlp5pE@Fm5JFRsAP2sfMess1WNQf40lPOMmdQ@jstUJ4fHMx16qqMRBoU6tcHx7KlH1yzw30ybkoNmn/ons5H6eRjOzGsPS4sFLx@l1SJ/WNybdcwUsmwyLurHFguycRrNJMlyFGlWFBlDDdiqU/anTT@MnsmAkNoqpw5on2FtFH87rzgblh6f5QqxqYGMI6sNHKKY6zZKkbULtTyvZZZUb9MKd8IByAFARjPaa7j4k1X9tzjDOMqSuImZjJ/TV09r9lJZff0GlDhiWtl2L0K4gMzMMyXZ8826uqKYfYllYLlMKXX08vQ9FsRZ2wlFfr4jLO5/ibK6x3aG456c9ClfYctmWXh7mFlhMOtcumhU4jxNDObM8CjdUWRmxJglhOLLH5jGdp6ZoDo1eyDVZKoCTDXBSytcRkRrqCvUETNzbPqhEjbnzytPRmJCAqCjQ10ExVdrdsY5NLr9Gql@1gGta8TGmL7CrbQDOZdYUSbsjgTkSFNxHV@mmIYrhW4Ym//GJoyiMgj6XrUmkV@RrWIa5Z9lo3USw3@BIh7qERhAttrBB0e2PMW5cBVmwOL40XyX5fC8Pr6mgEbDEvC7OHdZC9Y62HFcikELVsDHHsFT@fYV7XMkhXJfgfc@wCl7pEg07OAgIia6NkClGMEmKD8G2sERI1rxplryQ@Q40y31TT2m151Mk9esIg0J8h3jMbxKOY4Y0ALNxQSORYV10JYrt796O97hazdG58K03SwJEzozSz5/U4Rmfyu6zUjbJkU3AVNK889RMN1GQrafMehHaeRrn0AEBgSQPTukFnVHtDDLxJCMMwSSHZnJu5YbF@qA3dvyf7t8ax9lUQCjACQlNLByif0S3EPMEiIVAwJS3QyuOkAqg2oRwre8lENRIXCbU5StY7eEu26pUGITMrtEsnKrvEc5ZaVsWVVlNtIVLlldWUi1ku0ZpBR0dhHw3hxkqVeJY9WMwODWhbLoUGsDhYzzSZY1f2cNbWlMBGJuuCjLFS0c8hiuHIIeN0wsy5SLrAhPAlIV62FFgmRuqLV9ofuICUyFbn2mpBBNlrJodkFppGhvf5xGB@NXao6ofwQ8EQ00KQC@GEOKpJP5JBU/qxCC3i8w4iJYPe3w6V/qiZuC@pytXRt9Ei78W7Ld6L7b1nmTTQ2oC7D/6N@hxrSsGN2f6j1u0A4Ae8/5KZAv5hAqV4hdQEsgO3T1JPrrt@kOl19STt8s3dhv2iHicud4MBbMfAbCmyqQp6Yko@SMrCs3awpSD3H7VhaiWduxdWCComglLUzKR2ppcpUsws9VdHxhOmhhJK/ACaI/ciiibEo6tpn2PTYYPC70OKTCe9tsVqESpEXPEEf0qI34MhZ8obykrmEaj1rnQrYxB4aBAsYx3PgvReIlZ2JMcO@@by@iIdJvWSevnjRbL7yGXr95bLyutk017PxLP1cgyyxeZPbOPXldMyAy204xjIHVyoZMAnlQNQDBM0Rg/jzJgvXMs@cvvpYt8/xJff68aw/rsXX9YN@vt5IWY9E2L6K4WYrIDU6qPhjeqZ8sQeYNlOSENeF7GH@5vm@4N1o/ubruyPLwNXWTmpPKVu8fWKbtOrqdQwhCodkv1xZUfIa3lNnzuyts@Ve3NB83xn2/DmP7bhv@9tuGFwgQkv79hprKn/x9z/Pcw9plAc7zX3mt1f7NzXvHNswnIK561KOQ9V6/Cj3dPF8@bpYn/r87@U0/Jhu/HVDP6m5b@Ud/bK/AgP8GtT/3pbPiwfYLGd6/Ky4fs@PEorRy@glcNPTZtYankA/xxu63Z3luXDmk/Vfygf7sBDq90GSE4XH@@fLvaa@L/T@T2JH/bpihE@bms1prwqsiHwWaC4yJNaPk2yJp9Zu8NLJAGtjucNpLjzQ6M1AhidZxbtvabIKkBAnP/hbShXQF2GeHWXMU9RDpOU8mhwxIXO/yC@elwJVoDpwoM/1AXt9iJ6ZTkndLoJlBIyoNX54/oOHl2fSxoKA4BJPEFiJrtyg3rhUseYYgv/HjY/ckxiiieO5K1wbI9/OduUXXFPdsX/Lat4mV5MJ@0VidXL6hlMVxqq7xKGJZlEcRymLPGPwkkIWzIa06MpCjp401sf78UbR9@z@98T3bjqU0Pd75Iux@ZwQ/V4qZxHT2FlRZekFb2DVamf8XxsZ0v/AsaNd4ZhnIyOrhlF6cW8Rznx38yWL9PPKRNFA/Nqp5yVogGyXK9xGaDjAGWST4DEoASwg9l80qC7xUBgw1gZTP9@GXwPoOF9pjC0QReKobH/e5cuD03CmEJcFsOhQzf1hOPB6zAOZgFnTUOv@XkwCl9iYhiYjOTCQeWprP5IwTWpnR3XKEuEcZDD5UqmGmewIt6fVHT4J6FWKQw3phtjHIxTFyZEvNupU9QE1HI4tIBuqR5Op2lWnqPGTQX6ma9BOcFgkjg0BA8HsxEBN8fxb2ggNpSSFwRH9lM6zV5QRwTNTEV4kwOOKpzML4l2zM2qJ60nZ5I3zW9ZN1yTx@veE7nV3HEQoThNYmxu7eGXOfte0rlkSVIHmHGAYM2QQEGekDmdFl6CppAk0953lPcHuRIsSKS/uv4my57c6OERjd2TcBQQr7jqRSkVGEQJFcCajdE7kN0ZRdUcqfbmo6TOa4ECK6IkmYfbu3tbBBDt@LroYNrPFW03oOVZMFs2CLiL9HJsRrGfXqhx@DYci/cKgU0ZZXlREp3hpVrBfExuLTsekQ6gMjdSwIK7X@V3zz9@8dnRm4@fV0FM2cbiCYUlmbKuhVz@vEHfh2PM1MBkhFV4@dZ7O1tM5G5SrTxFixyD/tRG@4YNsG4gSeq4B0SxW/GpmvhZcMMqRrV9Mqqa4/Cr6ex7k7gYlxuCMqfbDhyNXL3yy2UM6UqwrzKSYC6xAdTBgenI7dkYGM@NQrfyCsCAcLduChQ5Rv6JlOscPKzVzJp6Qk81YKy12iEbWZxn4wgUz8oX80mO21Zo7QSqAkwOj/@ZtT2sEF@oOx114aMe3@n7zY6J23vrzr335lbkIULhMuLeTI@Xev7cuUSmOYAQj7ycdcjk//x3xetcZ0l0xm7qYfZ/9c7XyYvrzNQ/5utS3UrSh8lKodq7ehou0mecbdJPO6ZCbzpYyrX3z0CrHrjv7D5i13sPe/XGRt/3N7330OUsxiyUMTDD8A206HXw3TD3zoSINU5PJ3gH8jqG7n396rNPYMrRTyxM0pNvz9YfNaqViud1cAiBT/F9zz9/9Se08s@8Oln7X8yml4KXWWA6qcNsXyYnzTOCvurg0Bq4CoFzjsJURp8cL98Eoz@CtORWAkABuiVRYBxMSnQQSHxZB32TUObC@0FsHPlOfnId7/3Ip1IXs3DYYVvFdeK/dUdeJ4U/F3YX29CF325T6ylU8tGrqYD1aAK79SdvXn3mVw4Cha36K1ZFZaNniAMIhQjGxVdHeCNSjnSAqxBVpRytRwQD/21UnMP8WA4awWGlc319KzyfcU5XEH4qGQEP3HlVKG7m35zSziyjgmUc@viCt7Y/fPzGqUJdTMGCLye4vS2JaXEQq6/7YHJDTkFb4PI1lvH9rbU1eodV5onvt5tNDzOiXENrCV5hDs3ywpp1rmeBP3ANIoM4WnFhT7vebnAgS9Jo7bSb27sfTWewRfh4J/paAizER63lbZQu10A2DH19@c8ayMmwm/oPt9b3Po@O//nr/dc7z91@79OWU3W@S8htfxbbAMyCqzqLRcBjZ5LvlYDAyMV@0IiD76eNrUGzD5Jna3cQ7m6He83Nvf52uLnf29/f7w@39nqD/d1gd7vfa2C@capSv4wmICU5TP7Y7fB@3d4mmO21m/vDYau1szvY3h/ut5ubm1u9ve1Bc2truNcKNjd3Bu293n7vw1JbBk8JGKzmu7h3FDnw49uFu9IN3i61vf8D)

I downloaded [Netscape Navigator 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator_9) from [oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/netscape).
JS can be disabled in Tools > Options > Content > Enable JavaScript.

Navigator 9 is based on Firefox 2, so [media query hack for Firefox ≤ 3](http://browserhacks.com/#fx) can be used:

```css
@media \0 all {}
```

Code in polyglot:

```html
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

## 267. HTML+JavaScript (Opera 9.64), 12500 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;7 5 %$\24# #@aat"  /*{\D8gv ef26q--[if.q]PkPPXxy)\('#CO^"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                               ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .])[-'][(7       m>77*,68*,R@'_ 7 aat)(22)S ii/ \ipsddpsdoh#####(####### ??  #### ##  ###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5#     202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz coding=utf8 ''53'S^'   #z#111#y#y#y#_#    ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&     nthte \#184O@  nthie@O252< nthneo anhet    /112\   #####1#######111#1#1111##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"   ; L       ;    xo--o+++o++\    ;-----########8=,_## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> nM MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMn     # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>## # ##  ## ####
#~// :_   v>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>/>>>>>>>> MnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM     # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                              
#[#[]]xx  >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.----.>>>>>>>_           #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+++.._+++++++/._         #
##################################################################################>
 #{{{{]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-'4o'6o@ ]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ###
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTm
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}}  __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1] in 1)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[3+4*7*@]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit#ss
ifdef x
#  
#
#  
#
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<-  #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jzaeeaeueew_uuwq seee_epaeeeeeeeeeeee_ecisajjapppppp  ;vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;   %x:
% #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
% # 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  ***********************************************<>***+
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end      e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+
 -+3o4o#  +
   ++       +
 * *
  +***** %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+           =#
 #^=
+       =#
#  #   #
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
 (printout t 164 )
(exit )  
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}         @,-1,:*b5<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  DIVISION.DISPLAY 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e OOO
 xxxd 231
#xx}c uuu
#}}}b
#x}xa
ppppppppppppp;ppppppppppppppp
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
literally, print 249
   
<script>onload=function(  ){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test  (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258"}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 #ata",_"[];=[]t}=>+8;dnu?1&&166PLers951 6 4>8370::$/  \0Vngt=BFloatk:pext se>ExPrdispsminhar Cr~-<u Uint 22FACw;re! t$
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""j c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""J c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""JJHajyurbgbgggggggb____o""IJHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Je""JH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTZ-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92");return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]print 223;red[ ]print 221
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#:    ~#class C{function:Main  (a:String[])~Nil{83->Print( #~ +/.---.>_/~#);}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#ce` pS9^7^8^MUOUOF @0:8:8               \@,,1'1'< @125iRE
# | o51~nJ     ;#;#:p'34'3               \=#x=4;  print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|# print(208)#sCOprint("65")#9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>//                 $:~-<~-< ~-<<<~-!`=>$/ass#
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  +--[};]  pppppeeee*n*n*n*es*s*s*ee*n^*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*s*   <e 5>1  *///∙226ｐ\)|_|_Z222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zL1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2CgSqgAIJEgQIdPMDvM17u5sckn373gHR6AJQAKoJVKGrCiTQbHbMjDdmNZbCK49nHSNprTuSLa@0doS1jvVKDkvhCOnVofCTfkDLLxuKDc0/mD3nZFahAAIkezSK2CJRlZ8nM0@ePHny62TD8Lq/@EUMH3bk9MadnuMz3/R81nKtC9PV2M6YPTYsL5ddlSQMte12hn3T9r2CFGM6Y7Z5yQ7sptUCN@Y756ZtvTNd8MsyNnCdjmv0md81fLBYEIvtmb33/fc@azr9vmG3PAi5ytiRAZ7tYfOcGQ3Pd42mbzk2eK0x9sLuGf1Gy2AQwnQHrukT@BwDEM1zijPts87YM8f1TEy@aXqeg44bjG2Z/YE/LoMlDyEM13Kebj//fCbyJmOfG5CzQc8czeRFz7CXlum2ZmLoOvvqdH9/1jXLvlQdm@3fzJ@@yl64ntEzZuGvse2h7xz4s@45tt0xbYNltU0tO@u5znZc40aUDeaaRqtt9UzNsptMZV2zNzBdhi6s7bhQZb7Zy2fymfr2JKbWxLj5iecM2FLwMMPteODpXJhgNKEmBpbZYm3X6TPD9i4hJX0zMwmPYDenyaEJGQRCY288iN0ymWdbg4Hpc08orumSN6TMepZ9LnHqO3Kd1rBp2R0IZwJeB0OfyuRJTYhWZgNBwxoaWIywwINBFk6cvhmtCw@IF3LtDcym1baaHDnmyDdtD8rracyCuru0ej3WMnsQYQK9mWKew4ZexKnRM7paU5MQuZgK65/3mMWagwHjXlAMyNJ@Js/MvvPGYu/Av9f12GjQZ57VB2@/6bTbpsnemYMuRGf9ltRyJAZPczBTstC2bEIY24TS7R59A3jzEZ12G7LWYo1IOMgH5ZlKbNgOoM9lttHn1NAcjKn0ACaM0XYcDd1bjunZcZ9dOu45a5hNA4uNiXlmp20Me5Ci1cbqADqwPNZ34AuVaDPIFkT2ERcIGxOT5hYEkwmq1xxAw8TqdZBcoK6DWr50DaAP1xP16Ft9oA7Lj3vMNDwLORZE8Uy7RZQxCHmZA6WNVjq7sKDhASqGLsH2TJdIn@AyLAWANEJaVS5dyweKwFJssyPTcNmpa5oJTqem1zQGSKXRJCExB1PwsSAaEebWVrxyuB8HAuUxNGMABOmunn7nC8lgWokt14vwK8lyUao832NXy2do5jwTiHjgKkaClT4wL312ZsJvpDfSHfdaAqgSYKXH0s7ATxvqADKo@pDBtIFGNKkXWW3QiyTMtmbqINJseKgW1AYwAfZVikrWHLoucvcJUo1zKHTPsTuATyisO7R5la9noAqA/lpeipkXJtIAryPnkjB82gUKgX8IGuEsvMMhhEKXA01RYDRI13N6QwoHMT0f2yNgBaIixIM2@4q1DauHUcAfQfFcu6YHxIlxhnYLa75v2WZLY0E2iOu40BYvIDkDgJIDtIZ@hLdQpiAwVIRDRUWvj7/5O61OB@BsN5uO2xLk@hUQe5O6RoMyC50bQ4J1bKNH2YJwKUydR4cELoye1SIuZ9hjkQRlglK9dIa9FqOGemlBk@sawGxNYBBN3@RE7gx9yGOK9Y1zzhEtTrlQ8L7RgIqlBChtKrbKHu9CLTWhmRPNqP2h384zdVBhcS/9SnlUUB4tnZmQuYSWWFlOpztFIDhthZzAFr@Ncr7anuoqPN/wHKslDcZ@17GzTG0yuVlyBqatxKdgxFNxtxFPaMiplUTRKjW1tmW3lPgW0GIZEo4nis1Ss2oVasWZ6NEkAcwlgsHmairNhIyshhrFRboPwoUGnOwrVZgifo5XR5SjtxZxRsTMul1whxiJLkiXDhII8CHN65nmQMloegLZBIabW270mFfSGRiiwAWrlozH4slo0QkClHSqoNhYTy0H2VZv0EV5A5BiewPguS7SbtMA6vGwU/NBpEuxBtE19YTAWYgnXppx4NoNYKQBHVGT5E0O46vIKAWESROabslmK9KQgQlAW/a9G9y456B0QHnCngdYh42JGh2oGojMC7LNC8JTIpfpIp3bwFAQWsNkebVhQSPA5gY8XdB8pGwQfDXLwwA03kgivKdvjLFX46LBpMFgn2awPrAHd8yaJvIcYD4m71AwkSG1Pw/kXua0WUbN5nLTbexGE/Pd9Lb6XWDS79K3tiQsfLQxIaNhbRCze4bdGRod4BeODVGMZtMc@IJRQUk8H1jRbH9DjqroPDWvKy0/nk2bOpFAPJqkgUye157oCg3kLkJsV0EmQ9GPjwVYy3KBLUFPPpM6BLiYSVx@jUGmMvBaXpCFQAIAIjNHZnPoA1cDAr7sWs0u0CzmzuZ8kXdCs8mDUzR14OxqO0waM6OXH2YlLR06YTYWglCxRm/Cgc4VQZWnHKjyow63Qza8/hzATphF6Agirlra0ID27oDZd2xnDlBAZAgWg0z78HoASewEhWLouAKxixprKCmHVQR1BlwDWj7QX9f3B14B@gnL7w4bGlBK@tQdH/iHNhJL2nfHlu9wc6PnNIAte9A@00EK6eawYY1mCkRuYR2@8aQLEMDaHitBz/12CFSnxNseMExy38XAES@ZGDeB4G8ZAlIgDRCltD1ixfvAVE7GdlORp4hSTjEZ266cAANGDFHzBQpv09l8A06zucRg0cxoaQyV9twmGdSITIrgMThlS3owVbR75lF6IMvwahs9z4SvPez10Dq0OZdTuKyQYFfSgwfA2hRKzuoPelbT8uvclz18KGQKtgRjPBSb2igzJSDOAzGY1oChQBjR/fDQmu@ckLCrJKAgD66nEjZd13F5un7XdS4ZOWAwKYrUXaeP3J29JIELJWgY1lo2Du9FX0pdqTFXhAj7VJKX43HtjWPZylV8aWkpXoiXocdcWnoEpi00PUJTEkyPyKSSCcNpaKIYKTKhb5VioFstfl0NII8SNWwOI@zt31kDxagWCqu1lFHVxTeL3wTgGXoMCK3iB@DEE6USGhMJuXwJBdUa7enS72Kvd9J0rYFAwhfGhcHtAgurhAaoOMfFgUERhZfbcdIvuSBdwGCg2VXc@Fk1c1Y7uzprJc@u4ymMnSgapQYUCtJT@lrHdYYghiSqawVVryUS1VUQPhqleCa@oih5FYZxMBJJfJZPJA2ObSVuQm@onJ3FAakCP9Vm1yV4o1Q2kQhRBflAgQdkbSWuXeUh/UailkjGIW4inoKhWykeB8w0EQkeFRrb0hSCDo@/5IjZTSYlat4wKsXfje4U3HDQOx39aPjuHfIuDqMRUlhvaHApbyACpA/sIKyGnjOD1sCr0WbIR6fS@Nxp81HRLr4qT/clc0S19fnhfuW4RMl0De8cZAq1g2HTICsDVtyWBtygN2yZ0rwwwDbA1JzkBOcOMPFOs8lUh1EwtckzEekummwBNOA1JHg6TO31p4vgdSG/u1NlICDkTjFvk1@aQZZ48Ll5CpPcB469e/J0aoqsfw7yBGt6PRS@VZcXAKzpFe7Yok84xiiwAxqj2SBgAm2BfNkK5wJsx1aRFwbDOSeaEJ8QgRDkhtIWShLWVBgE3LZGMCSO4XyKEP1RYkXpf9exYXBqai@JG8oMGDnOVpnaXPn/iAtSWtObtE6Q9ME46BlN4PfT4M5kdgYAgQOl0/N9EsUbgGcHBzSOv6uMIEo1DRvx17JonDq0vC6iF8YS2Au4bcAqDlJxcoewdsCaIOV2ANPmyPL5qBVa@AlGeWJ4SgLHSdt8nIFUhjIyZiqYuSMB1mnCCN8EWRl9@XQJq9gXluvYiGStAqCBFRWxDmaAz0MvkNH29kF2bzF@5wEHjN1w1iO4jUKdRW7Tg9ZlOz2n47AVCICkqWmcsA9snOGEUY5vDKBFWe8IQdsdB4b60zRomuGc6fpqON40MGSawmtvoBdg8ws9CbCgzCcH362AGKLnMhnIf2DL0BMWMgJltozo2GSTAGIVoId0gzX5XXPQHbtT5OQ5Yt7Ep8lDaph8JssAERJyJVr4O4oabeTcBdp54NUKTPPKXqExAU7eRcfVU6WfklZ4s4ESxmac0TVAxRTQGxU@qV9kXGfpKb4VThWo7b7jG@mvNGDR@JJQQlYtJnvp@FI8rar4lsmLZcss3TIv0silJpBHFbM5F/bINJtp9MXOjQWGuegJPBeg5gwem15QTP4NcBDGnC1/J5lExk65C9PmmYZO/rQ7NCWz2XWYfAZDjGjJZOggujBWVgHzIADiuCSMJlaEJN8ZwrCuZfasvuUf0Jx9z8axi0bMW0OuJXx3gd9MABxZJgjkfMJh0sngvPqkj7I7PPwxcHKCCkN8jaPUNVvplQm0Z47jwrjSYzrNKWRD1PeFR9rxBi3NHwEAHqtC/bsX9PPPD/cq9aPt0yel9NBz0z2rATyiZdb7MJjtQXNY8GDecIawArRj2U7fghIFIN@d944dx@fCAy4c3O@JYcQAxtO9@tODnePt429E5qhHt/rDnoF5LCzPBAhhnFCYW8E0nYYDsoU9XAgJhIvDncOnAZQvXjw92K7vVY4OTyNg3gx7lqGP0oPzzqICfYFBmK5lOOoPe63pFR0apk7NIghmg2OuIoOxKVNVeKvoxhPFUZmGHigiY/eoqjgLbOA8t8uyemZzs9Uw8nlzvdVcW9toG@1Way2r53PtfC6by8BrY33TZO8puKqaI5q5AROfFcEJJEwDMk8fXVsLJBwYijZBYhnPzVfoe0vmmrmcubG2aWw2Nzc3jexGa9XI5jdMc32jvZbJmOt6pt3I6/nVWzMXyQaKVhNbn2aAoNXhZAF5AvNT4DPVHHjmQda7ZK1sNrvezLU3V7OtXGat1djM5PKthr5hNDbNTHttVc/qrWZWLwRxcUYVuEQXKgylShtE08BL1cEzIQWdabSKaZUxWIYWDGd5FVnMIFhGxoGD8FhDj6FYRMapWeGeQ/dgCRmnaIT7Orr3cQF5IsmSNXQUAfMUENeRNbcROG6iY7iCPLW2CqxS8M95/osjCchXeuYagV/iGnSkfFe6Tu4Xfrs95Zwl53MVu7LexHmVnPkK9PTaryjsDa@5gUN4awSPr1zPhXfDa27gEF6Ow8MV7/ngZnzmBQ2BrRMwXCGfC2vGY07AENIGQYquqk/88uS3aEldpDXXe2GkEPYmwear5fU3fLWiLhbLkZp5AzkFSeypA/LzUwvn7dtTLUYKR@BnkhxMI0xPJE18spNlEqZezF/fkaOAODOw7HOHBs6hqZ7R9BxCCUH0z3s3Y7ZhqEGvqaA3MnXTh/df/UabXnMCYKc7OzNHHjTtKbp@6GqN9DF9cAJ0Xg6mp3Knkm@Y7SGMgtINy0bzHcHUzTyFbDca1qKggAncfBB85wQrsOMhjESz2pqmB8NeXDoBns3nYU8PDilgw6BB3PT8P5tCvj90fYglvv/1ey2ohJtV1DXGNBYMDXXbvCT6aC@sMREVLfSaX7uTXp8QQ6a7QDYNXHI1eqFhPmiqfVXtGm4fh1yiuoFA8QWUcAut8ZzzuZjgOz@RAiMkT68zMNvqs@ac0BR2ZkmEJ0aD7J5jtAgNfChsmRTJxcrm1WCO@KAwIvBAz7MooTkrF2yyVcDvDv0hf@PugLuq0Rrg77YmKkJmckZDN0FENhqWeUulu8b5sOWoIOlRkTFj63PCTkpPk3Vqu2ecc2MdjfOLzwvoWp0OyBPiuyjYZRfGNjQoTV/S5y668OyhN1AbUFk@NByyUVPo35KC2@PvRUEssX8uNCzGmtWj1z0qPSQuIhcQ6QjRuKVJjSDNmkFzz2iMcaje/XQqwwRJwAGeU2omk5lV7PbCtd/oVqTF8bGvpPibm/Nj881UHCXzhldpvolK5RPIVGaxreqOioWOy@obPTXbihgXcvRg6nhimhOU5m3UZs/wgLR8UR3mBVQfvW4jd@yZmjDsciemW4h9kp1gC8Ci1WTBtkSrbjo9y8Om3VvEQWcX4CZp4nY2ekWmpK15iG2RzOR11dA0ny84TR@XchcQ2j24HF9FxXXqCOVoziKkNZ1L/C0ULbrOhcnf8zu6d3NzdQ@OpfaIJKzm3B6l1byLUnE7EL3m4/F8br78Zm@u@3QbCKY4ogO0e9K1Z/Ucj53Q@za0dFyIxt/zKTqKQcuwVVoPiprnRxOZGjBNzLIuqFej13F66/lO2oDXwsofum3sE8T3vtwv5F66fjf3CuQjx9bFdyHbP0@753fVHS1NuLhoHzHe0gPPY2FiUXJxAWEkgTtx5hduP5OnmFqaj5cXVYDb7F4a4@D7S/Qsi7Ab9CyDMcnbIP5hhM08GHyXy@C/TGprt6fWuh97ugF2465CRCr3vGdCR0bvG1XKshn9E2Pomcz9mVW7NzSH5lxeddh4Y@L@9ltGIffPVEYUY1nMduKMEM51hqHeifHjvXKNfTjabmUwRs@CRn6npDOX3w1ARh/gkPsIDEdouBmxYw8HU5U7NYqzj2/HXHcQtGynNZVJ9PlUjpS/W56aEuQ9k363Dq74YBDXtkprmUxGyDeR@espy22DrtUw7huLv6cSJpdJypOwOBviRozz05hMpULVW@eeipOa9@NO2UUzAhR4czNtW7bpj/G9qErmcduG4/Q@pQqB6bYslN9AKsWFn7uq8oZsJHaDscnch4czJ432olkP3iGJ0SlgDwfet1FDdOr1XtWs4pI1tNLOjPX2eaDIRO5dqUA3T5NLfOtEb7HgKWZUdC2vbdzaIrk46zTMnsE/o/W12@Btaqu3wgtFFiEn09oWrofxFbDJimpshm8NxoAsqwWDnK7ZN8l6y@jAaL0ZesFnYaCRg7853hqtNy6KN7CAUdj4nlpti4hSvmPDsMw33I6J45oerooL10XMOZhVn4vcg77RMfm5qtu452SqA7cO89HgxDh/0qPAd501IRrf@nE7KUBjOjfHXvCdC/DZuAn1OezfPVU30@6btFHproaupecuJtwhK9pdp2t3zS7fCRTaFjUPoEifn4i7rRCQ/063yYg/RXcpRTHbc3q9@2AW@SPnlo7TnpunCp7TakHUT4I7NhrgIT53TgFCX08Iok5/UbvpmkPosjzHdwamSrZFQXs4WcTfi7hosLjzy85C3TpDABgJvr8s/DvHph3D8QcD@tQHvaFHL4qq0vG6eVW5T8nchyosn2874nRrdpxGs2vdlaWGafi2dZ4OZoS49daR7SCCBYupe@is9SxAnjvWkBpKUf8T/BwsqlIxucS7rdAwv44LbHfoumPEhO84zOs5lxP@ML1/IpzG5asPaFiUA7EyOMebpAHcWRfsILtlCUQsJC4kMBLCUeBWzQwILPrCGaWp7Z2R1rG6yl@L5KKZ8lOmIuu3nzIlKrY90OSgFZm5Bfcp@plajJ7bWdndYce7ye74hH0LRCx8za3p7Q6eaZ6paF6p0AMZtvgswne2l8bt2/CtQ80NzVtXV3K3Lq9QOL2nGo4Fnzp8oA6HC6fNetbA42@mtrNzBYabS8g3Q43nD5tF/bTMNl8LQdNdkl7fcfEQEYgUatM1vSZOpSNH5vIT5z620wHOrPbYJHAQdm4Rbq5az63@sMdTv35udgzcXvnUwp2WvTlUAVBnF6/vAvqdoeFZ3xk6vjkX3uwC9l3gnhkdq/lkCvMBsACjYg8e/0yRPTrdRP5l1/Lo/EZguGXOCYmMky3SWR3k/XmjtZnp@vBg9O3TKhFBSez9ZuoBC/aIhwZcMEB/Y25a82binQGNG8dkum0S3vJpZlZ851LV/E0AtyV/OewPhp74zE@d9ulEp6j75@TuXVrAFtW3wI1Z1@j586exIzOzIHOJTnJiXCSFf9fqOR323XyGgYgGnTYK5XMIbge66yPDhxZhzyFgSvueC6U46aG6vGBvgSbMVaZatuXfPsHj@waMkYIvFoZ3NngKMf0U39rjT4Wgns7HyNNbJRjo28fNHh6K/9SRAGe7QIUndGgdjeG5@Sjdi2TMXQEw6F1s8zI6Xrt10aeAXapjD30Vd/nf1qes39qnFNgovx4hDaZ8p/LsRSJKIbT99S451ISB4NDrjSemhRsPZgjPskFYW8yLp0MHo4k9k1QaHNNGzTvibA/w9BSx/D1n3ojnaAy9z72HTNCBDPt7ZhNXHu9M@7nzDEQ36MoGwHT7xyZuGZjhJfMjYrSnTtPoAX5adyZzQmDn9BWTwbUxMBtQv72Jab4sNg/wnuEbC2QnmjikEWBoupNWrF7DdN/QjGDEvGhQO52hJ@aIhiGLCYa3QtVvNrnAjdNyU21kdm3HGziOzd/EhDPw0Z/dzmyge6DX/VfcNdy/PNX7zR2kTZf28IJvNzFb/ODeouK6ZsPp8TcWYQE7sC2@ucBwLdNLP7Xs4YjcmAqy2/xhDt/Gm9E2cJrD60Jju7RgjB3u7sXNanyrsDczkgKR@MLwaMl//phmaifx/XcVdQ236eDamTB84spZ5EjYHXw83CrNtyY0oFJGwNCM5jDQK3BHVnv9Rp9eC8ckkZo@Nht45K5B50d9YzRPiJw@OiYcZw5vBSwNG/46U45g1JO4uyObHbJNY9wa0IsY@uVcMgmSe26ZzXdG4g5eGrYimktOGzSinduQpjfBgZjTM1W/i3ss076/iGE8t86HrXusdQULKMO@iWvW0ys3C4nK8bpEEc78VfqQ4bqm2LqNuwSh6Qdm5Lrq9kKSRfDwf7jzRRo65vr6Gp7gH47UDrCzu/cFQOaHri0@9yG7I8fz29bocIBqnBx3EX/BYuUgCnx4c0DTyqJCQH3awx6f7@hEdnT1WzS@A2mw7YCpRyzcN1XTvlBJxdEoWK50jUCPzMI6nN0cqt@xO/TSC9cDwUMdePRND7yjg6eHp9rA02@ZOcQNf0Orh6t7lJXADQpIpsVT1Ce0V@2eixUqfHA1buozF7ZYFR10jYbpG2lj4WAHfU1/vuT35PTZ0@Tk5DJTdruu0zcTUe/dk5MU5J19cTLXOxp7H0i87YwWRj@o6HpiDg2@sGlNcBHfm5PSIkinJgxZgaKe8EO0d0pNTWdgtk7HA/Mr6BKR93r3TH59YSGfGxdWB5sS21yIKGptbFNbX6Mg4sAT6WYKtXh4KXEUD9wsVxz397RA0Zg4t0jdUHCCBhyNZnOIM2aQvsYooKIYyWQiIYlYT5xL1kctRhjJo@O359agyDKBEem0C5IGhUcFBApbNthWifTEJRJFrssDyBLa2tAssrYVgN72PKtjQxaCHJAaJlTRwjU8eQyGM34At1ply1ejQqagX7MSkwsyq9V4jvGhRCqjAelQOubRq8tGrbQcV9X4cvzMLrBMPAxu9mAYPze4MRUWMosfkeEQv1y/mkPK0UJsFrkKGuheUb1T17BbPZMJUoXyu1yRCtfSc4rbsv/yD1tC6xVpd@tbntEDhKDiOmg1XefyEU83QNdgYKDWLIRx2cUpd0xd3d1m3iVOn3NlV1BdL/ZP80KFjtCSB5YjPqka5oJTDq7s4nFgnxMGz014tFMkHMYKCgXjzGHfBsGu5Xc9jZ1YdNJ36E7O7gjdgbbv4vJNK8UOWMvEHbB0gJtWK3uOc06HujAnf/mHXHEQHeMWx2uD5ElhWCRFPK2tk7aeZtMZQq4DIO9M1xFBFESy0fSHuDeA9NWRewIPN5NGI6B2NdDnQ8lwpT672ydMrbA4asJD/RtFq60sbx9//lU1Uyt9YP20@V@/l05cCcTJn6mb656cYkGQ4jUSVtQ7B94T3ziTl0cyTzA8426JkeQlrw/U4seJDI@5BzTmOIOg2eDQhFSQhdQoVHsoaKZ6DhT79EmdGxGseUmKfegwpY19JakT9KCBgTVBoHmrKy0rQ75crZ74LAcJonIkA0xcARyd@kYlNRhlecTeM@rPYGyi5zJg44jsoV6kfmknOB@xGj23kt4zG0Pau32R1bK5EhVnuV7aKpMJZB8H9ZNVX52Nshn1bLRRqcFoSyD17Gz0WSb7NWDdcSHWwzS2vMrzvatlrZx5/94zxkyWr@NFfs4G2MTy1dHBUeXkdPv0xQnUwnXA2vb5abuA1yAV0QHartMjzW@AFxz2fAL/CW0TNoi6RRMJKXrUkYIKXMuqvMyNEdY0FfuO6PPie2bE/2YAwdPaFpPCngGowCBiQ6xh4YcD1F/HRFyhg4uozML@AxtQiBg8zTSHlxKqZFYCZKmArHuiii0u7CPudh@M3QnldrQ9mhsEMRamVw39eRHnouD6V1LugeF5f/9ycyi3l5vC3FJuCBq6BnH2tw@evjiuTEcLOnniuqXNnDjjy5kztjQ@dAqUjpFqDRERl/tLMpMpAreKzoyrPjX9SxOKJZhjs88jE4VS/mVpQpiAmRJq360JKURRKAco36AgMnsEGcY1kSwGfXQE3BUvYsgE9uUQdJBxTRaQY6RFVsMnKAZCFegKmt4RMXHBr@NeVPxJBS0Oi4Z99NDjbW5BVxX2Oh6D/0ivFJiyNTZiojvTa0xlWfj1TLsDBQ7CJoq8j2LLHBHyMs@7HOYXtX9CnlpvDFpho6M14ugu9NI9Y@AFwmCMPXd8s8DeDh1SDxIwk1C@IMWzBlfWS1XLVdCS2hEQ7WHwE/RbBO9g/6SE0hkXzYi/R2luaGNHBYG43lxxgN93Ub80P1nNFVhylDtCV2LQVdIslSd0o4VSgscuLM8COZ8qoY0yTg84JZZGFBx1L5NiGLbd80AmaUH3DRKKj10tCCcanffkhz5Vm8kxoEktFBlTTJYwrFe6qTsPutJLHHi85pGXKRxB9iIw41tLqgqY61h2oGi5gJqXaYKmwHx3iNs5y/EbUYIsFMikdv1@LxJwjhbRMzP98Td/h2sOPfPB/CNhHmV2wPbrwtYG828EProOtn8W2rJg@zG3vUpjld1UlzjJZ6j5YuEJWSDOx/KNgiFjCFROU4HCKsfq/urgiHlN1GSMFdqH4eOkrpDNBOMUZvWBMi6oojE4T2FSjxM4SvUroBMgLiASlHFQrKH0TLemoOa8QjqNGceFN4321ZojvteFFOm9HaICWZDE0uu59TU9DZlULwKApNung8f8OMBEogCMUbqwBqXXjSbb2tpistc0emZpvcgJJL1svFqVX4cZXYawEh8tVBnEgSiTGOBXFtGUZSOpJzAq9mZxPY6MreVwegORUCEDBEmgsx1oAwGZ0xGoAmK2zZFPYtM4GAUB17adiOboAJAKgDhsVHM62yYnR/dwtjjSSrVoNcgvMRhNlxTkeRRbfcXO/DO7JtTdMqC@n82hXxvM/2SODlxOWajt6KbyVWVWdSqWhj0@sR2cdN@H3DIlm86upvX1RIRCZQEK8ovt/T2AhBYOHKNpWm@cgbe9Wzn44vDo5IYSLgoZnw0WZ/HyVvJM1VLVWmiIh/meRurOfvrk2c5@gMporibT3hhiso95NpvzUpvN6YLUX/JTkjfTJo8bCemZ@wKmOTN1n84D3IQ@8U1HAu7yQ1o3UlUSV9fV2lb5zI7dSP79PMXKMW0FiQtMZx6pVY7PZhOzGF6icIqXKHhaoAJAx/P/eDDUd84n2gSEQ8SDBw@gAAeQtHQQahHzhAwc8hmgidqbLL/FwSPWx2eJSN1tmKNIyNPgvgdsWhMtjUI9Ydfwuj2rIUEH3kKVnVy5UKA9J1RLpHmDnuUrCYmmQEooBgETU8StD6PCSKPVeoWUKxOsFLtN42EALyFBIwB48aOh12VHziAyt7VnBqZjkEbY3pAv5Zrsi2EfwrXpc2wiizVBPlEhMiAqHmaVj6qhZQmFh6MkKpWE9Kqo9lAUXOu3csoooXXNUcvqAANXEilo6Z/pIFaFKhmw0KQE0Y4Dj@MY/hwPx0VR@kl6L0cT4EbV0Cy7ZY4UVORUqIF8iu7xy5cX8YR8gwZI@eZuoK5vRgtn0BANX7SIiQbLmca2GV71MKMmdXMTlWGhdgmoFkjxxHefghH6J6XdNwZMGZJ6WI9pjKzKmWKnPN9NMLXMNczYLJmkUTV8yAOkZgzaJhMRDlNwHlJJl6B20NWzW/h5Zw1YVde0GpgpkQRbxhm1XejKcS4qIcEoCaIUCGwJ65YVMEecejVOeRAH/SXSV8dQR@ocb9JqSvPBDuKCSs3KDyN6viYtkGN1c7MgamOa1WwyIIubXF5LA9g5LCSQUgG/QlkAYA21/uP1ELhWBGzh8ZembZuAIKCZvgF9sDEEInMTqeCal9RESzylEONZfCK0D0BGp7XHV@JXPdxQsJwu0uRM8Rr61Ndn2Km2Rbc6Tv@PaS1dvFKWe6VxGgSdRFlZ7pb05OpKMrlsryjLNnb1Dx/inM71MkgSdQ2GSCMIpC73EkWgZ5A8Sst2cdnYUpZbpewKxQArDNKuIMIHL61dLRvX6eWH0FOnwMXljVdZ9kgBaUbT9GvIH7aQ5XQKaOYK9TXSHS@Y/LKVTGIetOU6ZuBD@uwkSTz77CRN00dFIY2mO33R3Ga4algTN2644QgUzqKigbFnkbGLQx/1IPBEd/zqPL8FsgdP@Es8V8doK6/pRcV/edrn/oxF8Ls46Ybj6l65BlhA4EgBJKI1ZSQSwEx@8YuYvs5kZfnR@mrvIhnPZYrw0osbLMc@Wz7LrsVY7LFh@DBkT69cne3lOxfMbGfX36pq1Wprb2tH50dHX4/GiTMlHts9fCXraxB0g23S777PBssueNinPbHYSlqKpVf0hxvp9OvXr0Hkxada1spBEK2WqKrxWlXZEA798sbGSmo9v5I6fhyvQ16guAklm02cMMtKszNr4LVa8HO6dOOSEuMPe/QI0wMD/DPh1h@1yTjaNjudYcUYc3crNsTPvi/iPvvuy5cv0fCSHvbuWMSPcYgCXKxQN3IxymQ2k/3LP126Tl0d1bf@8vv9tLmEn0P8/Oj6GZpP9NxnS0uf7eysraUAcdx89N2jb7a3t9f2Urmjau7RmppZ2vqLP19ayma3sumlmufptXj1/Gs5m1mTtb/8/Xj96Og7nod1h88q08GI7zz8dJbLsXP2Dp7zNsN/Mr9rRcwGmhvtd9hBgrBcImYTj@dW4yev4lg/72K6rsfG9Fenoi0xvfxo47/95PBtzI@Vs@mXLnz92NvYej7GjWAA22pgu4iVY1sYbP06Nk6XSiUwbvy3fw/xy18AHPQZb8GrnAtgrY9jZbVEUd7Hyutg0LNZSPf/@d73pFh5BJkolw/2WbacXRFkoucf6g/JZPtdEDDOYnp@7fAxWS3z8WE2l91Cs23iTTVdGI4ik9H17BkTlaeLKsTi6vjmDqwLZqxTJ8aCoJM6ZwFFsZcxog8gEKIRbhYORDbc4eVsuJdnhrGykVzLPraLLyPPlOVX/xzjhWDrS49f76XTW2Xo5/EpFB6f1UUjS7ONvOw4j3Hqr8ieCtcivkaOqjoQHH5n5KjiI9AXy5dSdY6ioI0FPmxiY1GnmMAkC5vTLxGugs9f/V9/9dO/@gn9/ZR@/1mKBdt91OpFrRw8QD9y2ZWvzoTVfsae8ce24R9@gRVd0AFMtpiZjIVPuYwv@hc2MtF3xk34lEMLhZhEWRiOBfyK0pViH9JpVsBauiiXo@WBJx1aqRg852R4FindpHyiPI/gWYI/@ocntOJ7iVyEMwW5@Syx8i3P7R2AFKvGqrXaaMSmgNwKEZ9jDYlOE7Z6tEu5kGIqcKlk8hiIlAnahucsecfzAn6aVhe2tDaBGpNiv/KnLLHYFTy1pHp9XdVeJYtF8Q/SXTG04cNNkLXatapuvSonk1XKYrUs8rqlxtec@LrzmNXKvAD01uqvtgB8cqu6VXJ26afVEV9q7VW5ujUNg8DUyo8fJxG1jwFAebnGYFwBtXG9dV2@rm5dX29twf8Wva/FF1yvt27802fyLAgz8a9h/Z9V0@WztGiU5RrYNaBpcNHSZ0jc8IVw1aoUu0LKYdUaKdErqVV9PVdTGTWQFWBe6YK@kl1N50afrVeywAM8DJ6V5fQKGt5jXwnSzqYUw3HDJh8@bJLD64/f/h/4O/v47b8FK2QNbysk38Zb/Hv6Dv/e@vh32sS/47f4x07f4d@xj3/PGvh35OHf6Vv8227g32kf/6RYiTGQ4JYfZXqZi4x@rp@DwWIZEKC7ma7egs6HZUyWGWfGLNN39BaYTPjLgMnKtFmmwzJ2xtZ18ASDzzI@mtrw6cBfG6C48GdlMgg8c8EglR52aaSPmr7v6yxxJlVZ/LUJYpemaxlt3arXcuuDt9V4rRhLn52luSzKsmtF0j9@fc1YvV55vlevp7E9nD1zDif/h4f9qPXW//6h8@zQ6Tvwf3h4@OwMWFo5@TipPoanVE5uic@jWLn46KygIi0HVB1Lbz06K6@qaF5PAqFm0S35ic8EInzLS2cSjNVfvrwsUr9bvLwoXhbJEFq5oS4CiGDcALGKor8GF4h39jJNfewlPBcEl2xovATPwMQN6ZeXZyhRwvgh/Ad0RK2/gn/r/1//z14wpVpLQCO4ut5S6EngXyJxdX11Ld7lhKIIi7IFf@gAdoxydV1GIwW6AlNVSdQS19fcDd5KYosDLGMaW2WKPAkIzCMWpknp8pfyq/1i2vw5i4PgBCNrRSwLnp2NMplEsQEu4dqA8Z5WmBJF2nuz3MBVQRhN6gkKkVsrFvUVbs6uZYvFNWHZyBeLeWFeVpTNm08580hfXy9k19YSiWIxI8LCuLEYGAGE6RnNIjbyYiyBmeUtX8ng7CTdPBKXC/LDh4q4q@bRYJB4@FDfzLx/HzrV6y3LrdfRffX9e7ku4zad0mYO7Jn8@/fAdOIJx1WeO3yBWFF19lm2TClsOi6UagO8mZ7OTtLsGp7h@67yzhqkZNxv6skJ0haeyTjuWfznP/7@98/iJdy4Qa5rOgLAVFhua2t9rVxeXwPzeh4KLi/znUBKJ7mpJ66X0zIvLpOX4zHhpec3EuR6HUd/Fttij8rQUD182NV1jOqPreUSSmNsJq7AJXDTNze5I1tbV/LJTfFXWkqw8goTf9VqdTW5trKx8riGEs@NB5lq8cooxdPp@HXpyijgLNZ1sSlupcCTYMbDh6ubgMx8pngm1et726fbdbzQEtfooUNk6EgcWsL114Ebr9KUY26zVsWC1c7i8ULxMVW7ns@xWLwowqlx4PYsv0nlj3meZLXxSOgIgUqx8L0SGzB9YxU6WehjpQHtlNrIsBYuNrvMabeXwBGqjTVwX4Bn9nrBJR6XjttrXVotc0mKHT3d3q2cprJb0GVn97d3U9mTFzsxHa25iR29WWwVHY4r23uHLyDG0dPK9knl84OvKi@OwN2T3rwzTNMwh6Z5WR8OL9/iRQ9m3RyA6@Spm03LM968MQb0wJCF8@WPP/vhx5/9Tx9/78cff@@HH3/vpz//9qc/hN8fwu/H/Pvjf7eZw/fPv/1nf/Dxd38PHP8z/P4T/P7059/@1vf4j@x/Br//EnH7M/GLhOM/CWD9@s@//cnv//zb3/ht@P1L8fvtm7/f/NP5v5/@YPEP4/3kD24P8@N/D78/4rCCsD/@Xe6G3xvhf5eH@43f/vgv/gP//wvxh8bf@/gv/gxfwvJPf/sv/svH7//HbDb/F//m4w9//PEHP/n4g@9//MGPPv7gH2c//ta/0TPR1x98/Okf//c/@aP//if/C/3/Ib3/6D7/H3/7n/71//nX//df/4n4/Sn8/gOY/vSv/yPQ6t/@8c/w/yd//Lf/6Wf4/7//q7/94//1b3/9X5Phd7jh//2X/46//@b7P/ybH/zzv/n@twveP7z1/e093L/9B3C5fz7vA@c@5fpUl29/qfz8fbAxSQVogC7UYFkQX3fGJk1dfDYqSJ@xWHkFH@DG1Xw2n1wByXNlcxNYco3ctzAIk6Cd/vSffPytXwPy/xcADGz/M9jgn1vA60dkYV9/PeXJkjQdoia//ho9xQDy62ioH4HD@zTI4ZnH7yHE1@TNHxYGg3T/NwoG4ZgIFoSbzgCFwd2e3P3n3/7z3yePMC46/9oUyEzgHA29jMHfB0X9Ebb7SWmioX@ErOPjz7738ff/8cef/c7Hn/06dg7q2mZqOwWd@u3zvRAwd49wGHD9PuEgoI4DSBjwL0lZMCxt4RylpCdfv4bcL4EJBlsrUm4VbJJeJrOOZoiYBBsBGY2S@IZ/aW2ToQVcRuQKX5YEr50kXrSelEYl8KOgeEM7Q2M5D04jnGgoAVyMxOOk6nkYxrDRDkGBmKXkMauvlEY8YhIdygQByUZCp2NZz8rJfGkPEiyN9hjCQuBJ6TV8X5fK@dKojOA@UBYARnIHkoRQeAF8clT@APYSwYTw0mjvA2QlX0omy3lwKWEhk5Raqk5p6jkqHJU9yajc6M4Y7rp89BiajKznZT4RAqhkIjS@k5PQGBCCg/9ZckUUh/4DI/1WMD7U04jww924/yN0pvgiAMBVVdysBz9Vxdw8Bu8RB5WkZOGT5BAAc0mSnwKQ4EDCUFJKUv0myQLpQx4@7dlCVoHgsDjLy8tg2irLq3L9EEaPMExzzwueb7i4mEgiZIHJ65syOuPOJ76nc/mIhpkreyvw1uG/skT7mKksxRVpOY5zGHGeNUhLTa46a06MFyMoI9lWqAhJCsg@Ax/8PX4MZsARfSduOMdA/0npVUxiMap7aCwp/oaPViL3SFMih1clKTmx48yjiKFpKS2VEl@NvuSgCYNGvuKrLZPIyPiIh5asmb6@xhKSQleZJbCGmiYJY9Izr7PjjGC0kZLllL6Oy1AJMWlzWshia5UqhQy8v3EKhdIHfW1Dgi/Zh3ilmrjcC@gGL5bXtraw/stXKs0soRFE1nWpXBYr8EyXyieVUwh@esj0bEZjMFK5WtvIruXWctnV9fXcRlZfW99cW8/lV4Gzrmdy2ay@uba2md/cuA6x9RiYU6qw0shtlf/Rjed/@Efznvmu@Ejlr9lIo8n0a6ncK/GdoMu4Gi@fZeQiTXMRLpermRT@ZVdX4Q35TOm5jdrSUu9KxWKf0fbDK9zvAFmVrlTs@B7Aw6QHEnsATvBAGrgeycQOkoPDotgtgDej8h0Dsp4DQoZ6OANK5uCgRq@uriI/Kbb03e/6rFyGEYd6sC/FoA12WbA@rlotravRhaatoWuSb4exvYOvDk4ODp9rewcnMA74hmVXM5oUu76@boerOmQ12eHhoYTMD4Z2qzrGv26y4XBIvg2wX48MaRB9ioPpR8pm1eyquqqr@ir@32HI4v/9w2fhP4tviLWalfiByB6e5wnmzTaxBUtbXMVH2bHxMHgpuLRVAexetUrBdfbFdqla0zyoj2JLazitseb5Yxj1tSxv0DPGpXij5zTP44Gnhdf44Nm00lLaTWu4VVlpJx5l1zcKS7iNjlwYU9oMHHPo@CpwpXC5zUJLC9J@BtULUbOF7Hruekuo8CpDxjEHZUzvSmSjYMPw/Ro3qBaMNpT3qsk3dhTkbC4vXz/umy3LYGcZPP10NTfY@rp8HYSDhHCYiIN3pY8XaOA250LmLJNYEDcDcSF/lC1pSygLKdO6fBVaaA3vFazWtgI1ImXpw4cPI9oKUziwfbEnJruWR3cmIVt6CP39Q50bc@sTYwaNp6jy5TlUCfAVmz3Fre2@w04dvoV6x2wuCLHbNeiaxV3XgZH0Lx9mx7DPudeexXVPhF5PDFQ@7fUtv7sgxItBH0@smu4/GIRKvwEZRALiAXbg5fYcZ16ADfbiaEEpn4WqonD7DOmKguDHB58/OY18Tyvbu0@kdbZz@Hxv5pMTgXLsaWX/NLRucN8gai4E8U3l6dNZq/hAp1WkqZMlltvA7bOBRWcxwzfkVF2u1orQUv1rEO3yxZY9fKQ/fKivrx89BWRuQrh1tlbOr25kCoXlNIOm8BUUrbRDai/OCwPcleuZ5croyMUmBei3u3iptvtB3RqyF8Q3cMbjsuiaS8xflp7hft1NnR8@szyJzoDiFX54XacvoVqKlnNp07m6Rm9osuGALXSEDzqh0bU6XeiVL50ggNQwDAa/T30gfnSuBdB1q4PP0yC3Gz69OcFxg4jVZhlJ48jZzOfym6vZfCq/mV/L6eu5XErPpvSN/MYm9IcZPa@v53Obeiq/trm6Bp02@OY2N6QY9GNWO50GyUiXZfgWAKzdxFtntvD6HkfrlqUYn8xk7xQjARUe2odMNiGOjPcfAlvFIwkrVknOruF5oVWdAUSDNVlsf383s78vyztowbWW3Ywst9CSy2cyGzuybJLPLggWWVl2eBzwgmA@t2QyO7uyPOQAUIeVLHfRUlnHYZssW2jZ3d7fx3TeoCWL8SHYOffhll5g2YBgNlpWV2ncJ8tvQ3AQbpsntEY5raAF00Sffe6zC36y/HmQn0wGIBzzcBzCk6Cs29uyfMAt29vo8wUVPMez@iVatumRZRcsQISy3AFDBzsBWW6AEUlRlptgao4NcMMbflCvkQ1NTx5zBCGKZHlEoY3muQyjE@GOyTx58sTo@i2zw5@xy79NyBr4WKNhZb/x@eeNTqfhjrcrnx@jzxdfPDHejIduo9MQ0Rp1eByIAz7n/fHsA3k8qNeN3lyfL8HHnvGpj@sm5q1uvIU8iaeDifTrX4DPF@AzZ0J4xKHB04egDXx2@vDdMRrkEzzkQ99RoyEXkVD98cDECVxsM@c28IJU32i6ThHto9ISiyvx1Li6nqkVyZ31FZBGMsVr9G8rdIssSvYoo4yro1KmBqPWjaw416TIZ6NszpJTS/1H@mausGQ80rNryVEBlZQ77TiLq/ojRX@48k55DrLG6lpBPnv0SJWreu1RVs8X1jderQxlOVHA96PVjcI7EP7jIOHjK1HdqD3ayEWibGwkjXS2sIEbwBLFa8CIDx1RY@ib9bqiXJrGeSKBOcbuXUlcUXHZmIpqFdvKKDUq8YyxcaI4KulFrmGDZW7AaqGKpyFe2MghdgDc6FGmgJPoiqxv5mVIP51WEgnkSshH4Pv6ZbDGF34ihikjfzRWUPltr3p@PaHhKZm6067TjXfsdTTkZIFceokH2@hQe7D/lEaeXkE6xVEPdgckUFkNvGaa1FTA@J8rJ2N8Kkzf2JSkshD6j/iNW0Vh/fzJrgbjAGFDlVHaPgqqjqvhrdj@lA9XZxQ4nUKfpj0xcVdpM3Db5cfNtcoIBnko7QYeT8VRJ01oedBOnxSv1DrOx3/n9Pz09LvqdRTsCQyAeEbwWE6RVHDgAXdUsGW1mFEqg8mAobZCuQQUJC4JHfVyuVQv9c3@wB9DmYN4X3I1uBNABx4vTHhciKJf4RE64VEvZa4n4Z8P@2yHB6JzdkG0emkH8Jsp2qie0kTrMhvFRlK5hdq3dko7V8MCyqDXRbNkuq7jyjE8nPjILg1tz2ibR6aL5@IODpdZm5l4Aq3ZfX1WwZC7KEtfq2WX2VP5UAy13EhMO0WsiDrlOyFGrmhnN64VXcNQQ3mVKL4Fm7vMlJa2k3i0VmwpO6yeAJfM6/brNsuy9bUiXcagICRgB4Q5xIiRKJW/BMAc7nmhABkRJHEOMDGhZagRq0U@RmJgXRc7pSqGfo@vLVWWa6pafV@TykWpDNylOI4ZJW/Y4NemZhowKl8vjsBN31grdlmj1Hg1KrqlAYwjWbEH1S7Gx3y7uoFblwFJAOfde@Xjr30vsaXmStytSLDe90CQqGv10mhSQaulahZGz9n1NRxNr6/CT4dRdRY3Y6aymc1UVgd5AuQMiA@/DbCvwQ/CgLiR1XHMrfQUGCPLqcwoo@kp3dRTSua11XqdSJ0rIP8RwhIp36nYQDXggMQDJEtW@BqJZHalp7QcZmypRL/A7YpUSCPVZQMr1UUwx6bR48ETKltdUXrLCoZZPh0OKtVaoVAZDb6DXor69tF6ciOTfJdIFJUllih55lvCMDJGQsFgCahZzCMwb9ivZpag0ND@1GuoaX9Z38gWqsPlqqpD6TLvO1tyWa5BVV0zCf6iC5EgbxXBLeCBXEKbyFgTtwHK0z0TqlXfzBZFEGkgOLIiK2dycLJCicc3svF4Il7E2bMlcBccndhvHLqD@EP9kQwynlyQN7PgP2HkN3LAx@DruhS7llDSZjAaj11J11fXW9EtaV@y8dhIqoH1IWOd5LLE0rRDRKvH2BKZVK1Mc5zbpe3O8XZRhN7elWIF2iw52c/GzsTReKamlz51X0pyq/yKf89wWxYkK5FauCqriTmF7CoUuhWxQwG9K4ljlW9XSm8lyyx9Jsky8Ri@tp3PJXhe2YcYtWq2exXMRBSe4biYKUaBt@JqLfHhudW7yq@qfGytsNgHlkxrtOOunv4Qg17wmnAd7K788nU2B9i3ncABRtE@MHDoNHM5GWfzzNdscLL5auNV/tWzF4cvDvfZ40whX8jPTOefPU6l9Lge32KPQW63jiswJHvPnJz@wf6Cb0GNFWOFQXx1Lb46G7UUG5XWgs0Lil4uq/pWlj0CWmUF4O9tfV3NvC9zwiuTx3oWfD7@2m@vjbbyYM@CfFwAnOaS2XJZX8kmYoOP3/5bPEJ5Vflq@ymLo0KLv/vz389u/N2f/ytaKY9fF9Etu7oRg5Bo1Nc3YldXg6ura3i4Xy5Wi/E8rW0kwMx3ceixclo46xt6Iuap3AbZzcW890LDjZLN5MFv95Db5HXAZmwzJsXyz16/Z2wLxsvlVqdjZcmUTt9YH1kuwMgS/tkHnA/9oC69LpWX00AAOLm7iRGC@buVcrm8ggsvLF5O4nHgbI7Wf6rXxRogFR8cka3Y9Gd6K/iH9lfcYcXzwB54gxXn3rdMlivrDEZx6fTHX/utbHb97/78N88S7@vv698FRru5ubmuZ2O/gHzcckYvGIbR/A2etkNDOHxjC6531JqyFMM7P9uMhw8Gczh8wxPqXL8P2qQLlCYIxXXAowGys0LBVvCkUYqkaDqWnChKUihqkpTsdpopgsFWUJcutB3pSnqAXtBHsRLwJunBBBQ49FExULPu9YbugGQ@heLptRR7CFEghQeoSmKJTkgJBqfqRZZeuRmVZ5lrlSGpgvVNz0NtUsB/pQcQ5SlQKV3KwwYGnrLDkJYNDFXDIJRP8mhVIe0apN3jEerkqlDpeYAU47njkWwQo6UHeGSIxGzoepm1BQGKLCE9AARAGRQB2KqxLbaaYFdWMlmcKJ@6xn1uqHnACM7wSBgNobXw4FoQuYjhLK5gYuii0iUmarhpRh0DIBwGX5YpwQAAo5MNRRc6pndvUACLjmsrVDT28OEkV6WS1UowKhHCR91bqDBroinoRgIALBg9fdYqyClmJ5NY2Q@myQ4wnqTsAtWpZJgEauNhKrReSxL835tokSJnqoo8ilgAUV@8VTQBZRAZ0c7rsEnaw7IbCRZmvgl5b1KmSAlJOCQ8G32mkS6gJs/itfSLWKCMUsLLsyNjF0G3s4e4GPClIV5PhCfUOTMQx7P4xRXInA78IHYYC4pi9Sh023JhFEBLTIE6E2VVT2C0duhC@aD9bdk1hlvPcgn8UCwMjUovDFQgIdJZohlq0rzlDRybNE7Q6V3coEd6wDyJ69fg2R7alwbpjuKp0H62SI64Qi6kfNIXZXOlWB6Pi8tZDReGtAFuUszsaKRaJbvJFK7kDScR7RBcgiJRhmHsZyCOGz2zD1k6MU2GWg@8QjrdsfzusEFqDp5ZQFfdfQu6DdtLi4uQ0pfWuZU@RT16qtMGcVQcq4uxr4yeFWocEroESGFYzzo3@ZBUmToX6bHsegrEvRRgdvIDxBZwfhXPPmbAO8VDwW8DPhvcmE9F4i4p48TN76q@pNQTJBaQMhgXLzu6MOwIful5L4mBpDf2gkPPdAoP7FrIcqFl8pNPcTz6FB7Jk8Tp7BKdHNZw4nuggDgVnNVDI4iY5gWEUHUJ@xhgms3gECG2YijtA@oAqO1By0KtIL5bwNO1JdSXpTSh6QkGb7PP2GqWrpDn583F8XCAgVVfmoYOfhAVy@H5LagYjc8mAF@B1tlvgV8MleRw8sP4AXWjmTTkTMibLQlw2OlQWiXGm0VgyUUs2Dq4vjMo@hJ4rkMO5@RkSZGTADYpJ2QOOow/G51Tu0S8pMBuQkoxhCBQDVBQVNgxPK6FU6j0uLy81EirzNC1NNNDhaceXuKWHnQskEadtG/2B@KuCgsvGhKXqE1MKld4jHf@PRrRVXubD8f8K0ltPOf6dmi5phJve3HsAy@AVw46fTqyj4fpPaKbfYsUADcVWvX0BJlla6mrgMwKSGZqPn6NQBhDMKPUONVMAbBUo3meal@2isLjgtodAIfKMgNHVPjmBpa@F5isQTsM4fi0VTawN3rnTafnoOgh8xnTSdK8hEHIcWAV9oE1gki2ecm2XdcYK@SfwNBIp8qYpBs2ht6dfMAIvQm74nqRrFF1XJuKPgqjQ98VjD2Yiwf2pavbgXJ1VOg/4v4j8B9x/9Ek0SDZ6qjGJS90usbiIHGj/p0gJIIZB2GuuTatiQ9BBrmY6RwEhhxPuV3Dr1mi2AG@uQ3qsRQQBtAEKbFTUHte9axme@blSi2Z7gBNy4QIqHEAXa0RTi9boRmx37voDRxvyslG9TTQ@Yh8o1OzK6iB0wqWMawgIgyOLwu1mHT6Gp834f2@KDBAQHELPFEC2PYVK1EM9YeSJxBOVZ7gmGesKjJTIyFLeAk3kIo46jlio4BqEUDoHhYJsgk@LGg5Qp21YAIvXbz5Mwir0n0LpAg1XosDJmeaCmcpRaqkSK5UNcgmoB2l0tJsUQJ/qIrqjFekmNei/qPZX/rk7LehXczPPREs7xeKUrSpmCNU@miK5kJYZeVSpF4hB@kVo2e60EFVuBgqOmVIZiUdjCZ4OlgErqxUiVR@M8Hrh04hyLZcCElhXCpBEccl3ix5uwhQyhEeRvNEtHFACCI@ZyAAIzM3mimijaLRRqUSZxxstCDaZSSTI8rkiEfhoUcLMlkT0WCQFKrDxOqpoRY0EKhkgKfz3hI1fsrMMy5QrSt7g1pLYPAUpDnhOUQFgoZQkkY6a9bmpl6NZDrCtGYAICHeANDit2cUpFmGp6uhLeRRHJUBj@I2QQacVwCBEQsucs1USkhkNNQFuV5OUj8AbVdOViVZx11H9JfhPzkVOAY//aZjZjqkPu2YSc38/YM41hCzkQYaETL0zBoyZBywbJOiDhBLLh2mzBGewT0dXI@abvScRrpv4B4JvEc5vDQ1EYwHSBXf44HjG76ztlbggyCL6OuFCM4imuv5GMDq2A4MNaKa7yyuqc@Oo0LCptOxLc9M4TWtXAQ3aVmfqyWXonKvMDqeJIlZPz4sRdCcgFB0rdfxip96XfHMXjtRCNVKolVDOozHJRzPgikSH/iQAHo4UBy8o9pP3A0T1UKKaKdW81w5HAjPOCSyzYBZNUGeB98uiCrMcyYjQdLXhqJxw1fokoKu03c6IN6hLkaMPQP@YAIbM2QMBpSXFDNwiFqIKM@k5qA0U0ZCRP3yk6OyL7OKkQjjZ6cBTCEjxdxZHCNm3TnJ1Rcmx6MF6Z18en5Povk9uT2/NKqezTMfape456clvapMIEDASTZW785GSqg@vpGdqayEzihA8Qj3zmKL9iC1MKfbEHRbBNfaQB@p0OaRQhaR8a8W4f/2CgyiV@5bfQbeeHYyBn7Tx61uCl1L4AVLfgoEP0gg77mZXEjae/dMC8KCHMH2UVYAeZUYl43afqBhDmAY7cnhkocAfAfN436jG3RPm5BK3HNOntyLFDvPLq6ivXrL7Bljs6WIkKkI3KDExzAyI351v4IjoyOm5/BBnQKdVCKqKhiRzgMVFpCMkbqIKIq@EYYHsULqoZlvyuHBYvyh/w3WjFN2JT77DAJ/PB4jneKkAn4wHoy5lsQev45D8FHe//CaxLOYdyME8CB2K6QmySZuY5/HSlike/QIYVhtusikDynotpz@4GYdfhqK7i4pVG4kUimo5Sk9zotq3LqtxiNUEdAkX8@5H0neRXT3prkIqXFgExa2@2ldyA3IuEuh2VSiELnLrTXm2Dd4ArrRvJu9oFepz2GoYUzidL5F42qSLxISDoEP4IsTSF/BFwF2TL/OCSooG85RiWteGPn0jUFEahEuII0DlAgWA239lI1IKCkwQ/Cr6zDN5sI0mzfSbE6lGbaA6SQjgaTmVJKiFrB6bquCntn2F3Bn9MJBMnxuY9vw2I7h4rTEVdyKF6wUi1/EC8CQ42a8UFGAKcdb8cIeGbx44YQM5/HCl2CYtK34@3ghaBYYwAUrGR6ju2DhaG/GC7tK4lry8UKFIF0tXgjrFMI84lbCCKACyw1SIy6Z2Y4opu@a0LGRUJliSDFeCsdJNOGSol8G/rnmdH7DB3jinOUKBWZJpk91GpEeg6cD3UagU3NOSy6I3rxyuE@7fCaq6cE/CYO5aBwCD2J4LD7NjHjG0JdWKOALGUS@WZifI6ZP319wj@yI1IFCqZKn0yfsaSQPtBTyr0LgWmJaLb6IH9TXNAhegffLJ0ZelM8b2QmSoxzhGmtiTrYQqa/jtxQK63rmzgde@9Eaornr6UB4Q2AQhNcSgY3wdJDhaLENExs4g2kiIV/cu2dF49DsG2@USL0z0YgriJa5wJucRcmQMUQbf@K24kTiYdamWBB6VjM13srCfoF4MXpNeF1EUuWND7IQ4TnQws3muYlkuyeMFI6zmxT1FYu6oSAuT5I41zSbhMgaKpUYGj5PPRy8VlDVxKcNX4OYI5xUURBAJGaYCuevzifI7w6X3wOBOkDCTALzBOv5XelN8frWXnYm571JsjcrED1TbC8xVzgKU5igHEYHEcn8Nlq7IeLjFg4u5PNEQ@gz0n6AtnBMcAfeZscWHBZKCe7FtON5FhzPs4sRdVMi6V1ogdCiYUoCDi94mNNJ0W7PKy/4vCpGH5rINnqfXMHudAVHKw/hUQHcGZTzVo7nBHFta9K2SWEpuiBL1QuMM3Ja/gyreeII7J6WYsNlWHA4rB/vHT5/@g10uhsbGwnRR48n@cNWi5OqYT/OIdMO47A/mDNsyaZQYTcuXuO8O924uXRmyzd4CWfWIAzgRSUB@Yk2nhC8LMLPZ9ouxONhIxgVsM4nzcCY4koo6hjYZVsCrz4gxPSVFUMACcRbwHeKRmsJnJMF6sA7z@p16r7qddyMVK@LXgyrJljhTvwitpQeei5ddcjVCV9KXJsL2ztkL59sn7LTJxW2/2L3S/bN4Qv2cvv5KZ6KPXqx8/Rgl8Gv8vykwiYzCvjgFQs4oAS87plNs98Alp3NZNa4hphdZzDmfEfZTXD3E6PPnjhNE9ejtjyj/7jLLZpt@mUeqwLD0bG4tRsy2rd8n19P1gRwJNy06PQZbtRnELYBY9o@jnn7TstqWxBWwrHvwDK94KQU61lQg8Bvg1OOKS4k4XUPtBWIrvqiW9rwmi8Ij4s0AMbwJtfKWR6PYLY0oQZn8nwyBk8rx89O2PbzPbZ7@Hzv4PTg8PkJ2z88BuvRNwfPPwd8HpycHh/svEAvCvjscO9g/2B3mxx4BjIaw3PPdG/bbVnQMDhhpXmOS9x0dWloi846QzCQ4NmlQefwPBYf2sh9LKNnvTNb8aKEF8Hws3@0JsDCa9iY@RaXMoM1X9pPIL/w6CqT5QzbotSgsZShvRVFc4VuD5VK48JDf8zwShuzSMeRFTJPrsqhTTkty2TyLu45wblvfmqZ2nIAGhJaAtgIKtiAUmKkoT0eT20RyDKk1uw5qFaLp8Y3BQoLRn0cbB0pSoQxsfcFgeL@/QMb54P0YugAdA8OWZGs7/IAbDV04AHYGndAUfQA94KwnAgx9A@HyJ7ZOnd40x/s0/ov2wgddgwaxeZFnni9UZUabHIlstUf9EjHPp/loatzDK9pWRTFo/Coo77XC@6va5hA8sATxW1DuFcNQsrAbNq41CC2sdlDatjgC9SA@36Mtu8xpZTQ2Clu9jFti19e0OkZNt/SNNmKQ7TH8qiToiR2W1vhrQAtfh85ESDe1DGdjzDenpAKzfvGg5g7N1I0xJ5Hulkm2FJ2VwZ2bmTglwEDgNSpkU6Teio6k4lgnLYgZcVzgCJx3vZDNDyQc2vYNKciBLcLvrHevUsIJKemxknBvkPKHVQRXsSY4muWbceFNk5stY/nS5ALNrvOwLd4HSrTJZjcDQWhsWOD1F6XylOp0X2QMynajh1JtAFUvCDVBhDlfVIliueL5CH7Ctp6eDkV7aPD7BgN58KMrJ2lcBHp0sTpFxCE@cV62NvQRalC/pQmvOMDXXaYL5X3ds7UD69TqFqfswV@nVSwiZBfjtjHtKB50DofbUB0Ue4SLS24n8EbNjC22FMnuCW28gAYjAO7FozrHteLoR/fPnzTHQ@PzLqT4/v3JR5LRc7EOfLQ6yoT7pZi1SDJFMWpMbHXI8I7IbPA65XAJUUwQ379GM@JYC0UASM28hG61nT6XgTBQoLSNYZt4Czi5iNR3SH8BCvT1olAkKRHidZH@pWyU0qWE@nJzhEWQacSsOhUABkvRprsP6H@6ga4vdvBAf@@P7j8rbnj3cMnQdu7Fdon5U1NLobFu6UIrPuD/XALWN65/VJgoeypxYB5J3kTWkjpIXGmlmPh7tjbU3x9o@6o7QEY7HtxBiUEGkltaNMSdaD7UuERElEwE4Ho5HSvcnzMZD4@gbjA93DI0BJsEGEv8Wsj@O5ZyyZmp4VCUzhYDoWnwGVq61p45OOWxjwXeQtYhZBBUgIfIbOYvqSRuJ7oWUiEoN30xBADzE3n7irgQV5VAL5GZafAvGITMSwsoDS3mDHe@VhedFO3wFuKy8bRPfm0Y5r33XjdkjuOAopu/jE6eFJkfv295PJxIUiHC1jm2yEVuAWSNN44qrETSHgAATVtugZvqZagSnHTPBewYwHucIdXZlrC/vsTFBESF8K5LBxh60I4Flnj8vFyIObQzkPsBgzc0ik8@Q5l8AhYPLlsRSs0Men0lOkuCIRMvAjocZQqIHrtuhjeHapM@slSKJBH29oy5aYa5LKGs7MCdnFxoM9wb/P6LHuYTQq47a1Jqb@apHgvMZVSgPO5hQk8AfJ6Lrd6F@zZUgTR1b8vbN6HzPJPvz@A8f0EpDf2aHofKPfgeSrwnxDALajjW@WDBjMTEUSdOX3KVNmpM4rmD/LC54UgM6hTttnFa4@mU02w0Uze5kPnPVIUOgW5UYZIEw4LylvNDexf354cMuQ701v69PR4Y8NAuEfw@hfh4bqIcpSIEx4TnXYzXdemYPxYUt/B42N0GunWM3N0aI5vaOWFQU9aZosWoC0OGfFttalgioESoVlFDa9Jw0m94uysnqoXoyXcP3haYSuk7Kw9NQUpu3IiwnKWLPu2DBDrpekI7DXoKN5nXgF@kIdUABLQRIfyFMJN4s68EUZAWK6Snn6x7VOwVH220tte07BRU0dKphuGH0JEmnytHO4n5k2oZ4pT8SFz3sBWIFZKVjWZooIbzuMipGkQvDbRPdJPSainXmyQvOVSVSOt5zPrmxKVzk75qX51s5ZaaZZkBn2uYfe9oXvZOu843Ys267HBm8aoOX73lrHcGsMjvtmHXK2jvl7C060KQzUgebaZIYIVGXxEKirPZMY00s2H68lsMvwuLqHGQXhorFzAExAzVMpW@gEV4kk5v9SvrtdKdilT7FftWhHP6vnJkp/Ukwo6PITOE1gLX5Cv@jXsSn8RnW017QvmDhtjGCWFZz8Ynf3A/h1nuMSebZovp23G0gPcrIZnSDTbvFTCC6ORMiWUf6QHdIhHx9PeNF2Msy0tC3IA2E@BsOqN6D1OSA8y2nDgO@QjElKRhNh76730IDh1lKEJAwhStWpBdrYIziSMgus@3HXMd0OrOpfGdDzqmIiAqGJM4nbymSzjEUDMqDh6Va1JnmYazS5mAq8GfE/R2NYWvzP8Grxpkg53ahguHXzI1NCI6xvwGdBiAiZBgrlHxzckKD7adTRwF5qC8um8C210l0gQRB/cxs2u6DgSxd8CBHDEP@AilSZmMIVgBXIiP@pHcweoF256XI@rCHgKklfKAywswubplSbAacc34QiTFWgC9weXiE6OK3hECVSdbDeKEYZP8OCEElqGFjYPcUlVSl5l/PQm0ZRINDWIFgSOoOLBndjAiSwY/TwzofmM2a7Z60GmOS4eTNCBRjqOK9JPhul7VUyzFmae@6s3/NUpf43780xNQmnQf08CFaKB5NjVJNw1kyfBUjfSKjGSTTSo6aYGEsckbPG2sJ7mO3VrErgcViWnytBja8pDjfi8mlP73GdpKk5I4KF/lfsL@s6Kmg9zORX28XT6@JVEBZm0N1ZsJZmhUs22eo945xT6IJnJDC@h59GxvonseKMURyYFOwEBDafxqdmWSxMoST3gONRm5PLWY1kTwsQjZTYb/NDhjYY1p41EsERpJglxIzpfCOmQ91IEBMFEQmNByy0Hkcci8jgCFkMtBcnyQ4s3GjgUbbaJl/AY43t8BY19OnNBuNh8zwc85yNeeH4YeRpBxHSX5PlomuYmeOyDO4pC3dKLTNIez0KczySeRyZ5wzRNfmS6jbPcSyGfiDKKgFPcwHvoIzA9CaAH5LuoCtHzWvpFekX63AARetAzR2wbRxEGnaaSps6jo15UDxUaoWpKGJ4PBj1cVCTB7pJOPAvdHNkcrqZMIEaW0TTpADfu8PApNInz4xBJY4cI@RL3f0w8vGGnw2@cZ6jHCFgrTqhYviZt22M@XwFtZjXLT4WbbOjxRVEYzHeimeA1x1sPYpqua9ckkMU8kHIkXtQ2b99iuhyPhaBKLejSCpL0naHVPN/9HJdrN/TMqh5B2YVY7c1oq2uTg1KApMAjmwFxNaevSVJk6bfJl35VBJhiT7Gj/wpo07zAa3GlbegxKKAHwqlnuhdmS5OkYzNc40W4SMq48IjHpp2h2@RzNyBb4XW6eNrXS/HVLqAw/GL/zFeDm7QUlpJwTWqymAxVfWG1EIHBgZK2g4u/tB6Bp/o5PjBS3/QBKSsJNp0lWloWeSHZpY/zTIANVEsSWXoI0WA7vtWEmqGJKqkHoPgqxyQxfvl3JCeQXrNn4CFfbV4G8PTLBANBBoKVotvyIIk18U/KAxMFC5bQjaBm0sD9HGor0NxN1wLuO0Ew1QpFi@QdKvj0ycEJOzncP325fVxhYD46PvzqYK@yx3a@oSVsXAcn3a3syeFT4C7hYjlfFD8EB3n7BGLK5CFtP/@GVb4@Oq6cnLDDY3bw7OjpAUAD8Mfbz08PKicpdvB89@mLPVpcBwjs@eEpe3rw7OAUgp0epijVIJo0iccO99mzyvHuE7Bu7xw8PTj9hlLcPzh9jonhov02O9o@Pj3YffF0@5gdvTg@OjypMCyYtHdwsvt0@@BZZU@D9CFNVvmq8vyUnTzZfvp0pqCHL59XjhntAYiUcqcCudzegaEqpkTl3Ds4ruyeYoEmpl1AHmTwaYqdHFV2D9BQ@boCxdk@/iYlgJ5UvvMCAoEn29t@tv05FE5S7sAK1Mvui@PKM8w0YOLkxc7J6cHpi9MK@/zwcI9wfVI5/upgt3JSZNLTwxNC2IuTSorhjUSUNMAAbIE/mHdenBwQ3g6en0Kf8eIItzMkoJJfAmIgl9sQdY8QjLscsLSApMPjbxAq4oEqIMVePqmA@zHilLC1jVjADRO7p9FgkCAg8TRaTPa88vnTg88rz3cr6H2IYF4enFQSUGEHJxjgAPdbfAOkA4m@oFJjPUG@uBGIVQooN0XVyQ722fbeVweYcxEaKODkQFALoW33icA5tOW0FJkssRycGzD60QmU9k2nCxMVMN6ceZk/FxMqONo93KuAxMf1Z8kTd9QunJ9RfBT1g44m9ATrlIKZltkYduqW3XbwqGgYjc9v9L1OCq9qSMDonJ1Jt9zWIaZRKELs/2vvybbbNpZ8Nr8CBm0RkLhrNwXFkm3dOBMnd2Jn8UgKBZIghZgiEQK0SNuac2Ye5gfmA@ZT5mE@5X7ITG3daECQpSyT5N6TnBMLBHqprq6urqquqi53u98cdEHPfdntutW71MyAcVsNMXJ/rJQrY8TE7Kh4o33n0SNG@14GUfsrcoxJbnh4vIAlGfkr7NjmXwSu1WgMAqmGMfjYsLIQxXwoco4HJcAZKZQRLy9IuyQDBP0OhRqooqOar/e7aAVFv0cqNI3hn8mH9AfvDcYLYM5s1Wo0UIclMMJ3geqGO6HMBvSPJBYIh9RlPQ6CNyOnaXaHKn99NJ0OHNdVdahsAmrgyHFvqd4LRrnqtXx9ApYOlSXxe6zUbpJg9OmyoMySeanPaGQO/tNN6I@roOHUDWgTpa7IFC22SWeFq6O/UdWSDBUYPEGTjCLfi4Pvnn@LylyzvdHJvf9Uv@e1hd6AmD8W9rtjqndKfz495QKwwCilBqAklEQXjYZRR3mT6MKXUPAcC1FmfNqqzwPa1gElIMfO/bHZJ27Gs3BhQg9s@C9fHbw4/ProCDgnQruxs7m91SnpJFnfVfnva@yH8ppSjrAItnEQ0@iTsUqegNxDK8XIhJ2SPxFwo4EFMde4mjR6iekatFdG1k8J@RgON8abPCbogGcHiAfbojwa90uKXgtXphCAkxmqi6O58Bck4fsgKhENiKvKeEmztsB/sG29/NUS1wMSAhISo2yyQLmgXBDfs4@UIyjpNpRmB4vUbUXHnHRN44AsXeQdi7Gz9Eto25jFmB0Vcb3StFNNAOJ@HgpLeU1MeGX/ldKFiJ2Xcn3Bm@@E3uDxtaSjo@R0fpwcJC8BjUe6JpqjU5uzDPpYWj7d92CKVlZ0T3sWGvNdAYrWnliNdX4PYzUQKKfoMuhZuYY7Oh1Ivkvyb31cca33TKmYgwPb6QjFym@g3KLhSCsdlQZEfqvkEha3pXOVMNYudR8lVeS1Tkeh0JlB0y/CB7X/O@KkoP09UDih9RRbRsq@O2GSWmVcgfZKSAkv1XmCcYiRYtN89Tpt5sqcmHM9MDmkWXD0DKBAZmepXrymJIVDpwABSORo1zDXr3Y4O/dBc3psu1Idj0Mm/YvIsWSvUFvFtXZPqyRzVdUBCv5wLZcNTUZ3n0NF6zH7yCWicAEX6y2th7HNbay1XJW7o7FKRg@9yok0z9kRNU9OTVlaavFLmiRjlxnobEcgil7deCK3ahlZLDMMX0613I6Z3dIcsKAN@txHQAvHjR747IqbzZbIuc9fUQY7TIeNOjNuRZJurkdOl@MA23k4IMsIXjGaXOJ2MebWKc1e2prlPCSnEOwk9TBMcwQi83XrgHXaZC819GSmRHrV0H894YzyAZu4VIk6J/MQCM3Q@Lr1wl8izOO7jdtOO19DtO5n@38@odSD/YR3ymgak@YOvaCm/zBOMaLccGAfSrEk/pe2otHwshYu4A/1VZORqySOoDNQgskiof/qRoWA8ktmT0gt@2SijUiPeCPzHirxBZ947eqn1/gkdmYPBgXAwRs8ThUxCEFGuQmP8K6vNoIPc8N9GwazgWmWg9104EdoASLxezqhbVdZrySDXN9P4mAJUmi/ES4a1EbX@Wx6Puk@mY79UTgNfdAVMIX2ghcgPi7pEfN/jmbTy5iuXKEPA6PQYJk@cwYTzuiFv/XRWMfI8hQnQeSYJ@LJbHlwzokIyHiLbmaW5pmURDXKp9vSdTY200qlbIQjeXy13M6NdddbRZX58BgbkGW1nzus5yjFhEJfjPDGzrUCvY8VMGDsWTXLd2/wCctAvAsoopOADMQKmGsn4OYgUDu4EeLjwaI6oHR2M0zlEzwN8NKS2KHXVR9vhgRO/wkeSj@yWjtNoyob8heY0g4fljeju739O0MPAPwC8FvrRdRSRAiU0Heo8vnELDNLXkqAhRzQ0K2yipoAKMnTWTgCxXacabS7yLea/by8CRvkZAJbs2Rsu0aVuCIdEL7xgi6nCyynu3StDx@silVxKTME7ogHidO8mWCD2zw0afHjOSIbb5AxPZGWHQPom1DVByzhtYA5B04TZM7Ce/uKabfvOms5BHpFTk3GDQGOrfZLinEQmQdPVqYzYMZ2DnvibVCJk2lUuSP2buQdhUm@inDdd91bXU2Z2LzFWnt1QKj1lvi47JTy8OSIJosxcmoCGkIVip41meeRuPC6uN687vIWPNyEs9RFR28qer4HvPZxU3yLPqNqo9FLimDHfJcd/f64CwPv3sxBpE0W8bvEMbrIMrpLfjSayqFJY@nuGCLqE9hz@BgA5rDfAeDOnJ8bkZr3x1LZM9WnTL5ExCem@sawQOBL0RDP/zERGR@RaCbFWc2DR5jYlU6TWrUe5qvFD9wgBqsEtdQWwlbEdLJydET55IdOFx1WWsiJ4GnfPGTXaeI1wiiPuxgY5NC9u6y1Tjvc0kK3BLIslfpYSyqiGX4edxfUyjVUwBIvQIUe0TXedH73Uf3SsUA5aIFr02fxJW1WcTCutQbQwD/mp@4CZeC0K6mZWVHZhdAl1gBrAdSQ0Thg7Qmlv3DGFI8H7LKMQLTn1w7@WZMamAB6q6mxjVUWgyUWcQXdvNpcq7bPVVKC4t@IflmKLOqSugQNBAwx1Pda0AJmyCTo0TBNyV1MyssAKnMEFb0WLkt4SQk2U5fCgu@IVCmwsWmUaBaV2DXbqBU2AoJFcZkUEJBZioukrcBGVwiLUWK7eDxpCRCIFe0zxmEqZFayONQzxwiER4JWc5TjllVtCgXTx41NN/NR0zd93W0aX5v5r4AfDeFxrZX/utPMfM10225nq2ZqAj5cs9fMR0CFawKsucIv@4@CH8zs2dot0VAyMlKGuAJPUJW6RL2t/kNs7VHYr5IxVHtm7LFSv7p8KUcmv/fHc3lbkim@88sHq3wjFSCSXJ4Sn6loCof1QRJYbdzpcVSo6KpUbjoCXqm006H1zaujo0xe0d5SubpcBLPNZrOJNNwz06grL160X4TTRrZ0YzgfjxvR5Wezb3oNYv144/Y4nj5SCnQAMwJrIq5PZyO@SgBhgKJYuiaRkqjqz4dDM2c/HpLh3MGscUkJt7do/wm128U3r8jAQ03K/nqGA8TxnVl68V36LGdKK@okBGqjU@pbWx3gAHrwxRA9gfVhCTWGfFn508C25Xr773EDwaswaLIoEa77PnWQtT8NxuNp1fp2OhsPMBT93lW@wtGRWaHJRfCQi8JH5zElPK1awdtwbASuYhGT1LE5tS@piwlUhnHMsv5VMHq2iBz7@HsbdhUY8hoOcw0zHVcte2S7knb8Ds0yHQLYdyp94UdOn/CULww7vSzg9AkgWm9VC1WfTBGXrhgRnN1eGpFaDG6dsgHA0F0SBVRWdJpeGskNxTVy7ZNFa4g4bHIbAhMm9bhbDYxl@v244ttkOLwbU6SE8jyxvzlDJIs0rUBZfoBPzMf8TzVY1ke5jBUs3@C1D9f5DlboYoVS6WHf@/HSOTg4sB5Ea2vWwcEhPNRq1sHhgfUUXxweWk/h9yH@XvHam5sd5rlP3ffw8lC9vLIOoQ0ycK71z2dP4Sd88zAwCf2FcYofNLwH1c6Drre334kbxweHGDcOT3/7t//427//Z@NAfvwX/jikH8ff60L1er3xoP/@wcpVB38fPz2tPOgdP4hOK6MOUhmy@69nsT/2DQfGer90S5DOYBz2bgrc0R4cYUzeguix58A/ngca2IcP/HSSpI@z9BHTcqbV/XF07lN1i1rY9yoHlZUVeNrzKv9SIduJvPf1@3fw3nKRl1PcPqEWr56xDl4@ef7czHyNXJ@k92GAaVrwbkQ5NgkncQiDOiurO@dqx1a9bp3WrDMNHroadLlgFkRWMxmYfxUg1ejIL4TOT0VtwINRMn2zRZ7PSS7iEcl3ynTO92/5oqk8HDziQx1qYw0YHpbvsLu0hF7i8AFcPIXxasetrc3TWrlcLuk7ubp9YnPUW0R96Tua1DEuncFwJFAESwbGznfcIy6gQURGuUw3Nq30@WYxZ4KqNWlMrHCXK4Y8j/YmGkhJszm2cHM8P8pYqPDRLVhWPKdAAJQNlnc9UgIAKMJrjxiXxRfrxlHQD4dLfeyOlyKkvcNeiVFbq9bwWtCWZc96tozr/jBtEBCCUgCli8FG8w0y8qZQNiRux2NUv0HcuE5UZ5J/2tqgCdZOKdF0vByNoTOH3HniS@BOgHlXJms8UdFc2APX7AVDvNSdVzRPWOpOinD3AjRFTPqgYA7wiqIxpoVigY@PICkhIqwHlHDkirIhRiM44wk7sUyH8AgbPgZy8XVsRIZruKUKQaFSi8qxuuJM@MBq5LpWxCURq/A7PQAm8iATJOnDctda5igwcqUmvt0TSovwdjlUpCU9pSsryaa1og9gQaq8wAMyPBwDpGDJOl1nBaxhaZ2NJ2d6/HykFuONeHR@xhfOUTdtPiMHjqW7URHb1B27o9tsXKXLryZ@IuiNpnEc9gBZyVJNE2XhY//1GbR6UilxZ0IteFCHCMZXq5FeUeb4FCkFi4hCxBnee2janSgqyBTEY0U8E@Oz4XLmpHgyndSI5faCJOyzEx/3fl/x4giPacl7nwC7uSNQHvigUk0w9XCiEtzIGSVNddoO4Qn95XH9n2vR2yeciZlXWLTELgBAmjj07JykSEpb1JRADWSRIjCSC7Jg8F6GMMfBKEwydaqSBIA9n3kUVwr1uMjPEGATuznMoq8@rcqesc@cCb6VewAyXvUNGO2OK/G3RbSnBoO7Gt99qGvykCika@c6fWh@pMAxoYYVDOjD5VvNzhBtrrjXUR4zzCY5yJKqlc7CR3ugxgVE5herFGNCDQi3yOOkdgzYaOewAew0twxSLtzMNG8QMBK3uZMTj8qhl6eLRYJrzFvRi4IUieCqpKNK3v9/95uZyt4MQ2Rh8UEppAPYo1M3B53KId9k4Qq8DJSgLvnZgDXO5pgUjd0nZEfBLCohL1KjUw1Hris1dJnhGklKEaXogJ/HFXMuc1XVeNPap9natQpHFb1XsUWOIelEroQcydd7vJm3tjZVuxw0REdv9OtKRTdJcJD2mVCzIyin7dUfInrQC4Ou@dGTc1VEGkqHV1xejVkkCxAuM41TW3REI@VMT5QCJLGvwsE8mT5Pfn2ZntIby1mffkk3foJc4IMYLCKC7zbkCR7RA9b9tdQC5AMhMAL2ofLjAJ5LJZY8RMO0X8Sjw@nCaVZP7BO72tradW3Sk7UcVu7HoBmV@wEn7MJbA0X3pMSAZNd@GzALn/XCwSCYqHSgUFV605@60uwxmvPfa3YX8yWrNjHxwDZ4eVyDSaQXgmt6jmb@6MKnxy@mr2b@8jlsQvTzywnP50ts7yvYjPBaIPryFa/RgwGIGvYV6skpTdxpiBSy5IPk009INOBkcIa4UICA4BoCuE89/jg7WAMN5vjZdqGlZ9o3YVLPWEKJ2ZH3jA9Ozkp85@wFXora5XdAm45xKa080qfcTckiI@AH5WNmvOUaLOqP8aQnmGTOIVT2WiE8vrmYa1WtMRBoU6lcHx/KlH1yzzT08ZkoNkn/vHsxHyehjOzasNS4sFL@@l1SJ9WNyTdcwUsmwzzujHFgu8chrNJUlyFGlWJBlDDViqE/KnTT@MnsmAoNoqpw5on2BtFH86rzkblh6X5fqRqYGMI4sFHKKY6zZKgbULtTSvdZS4/6fkb5QDgAKQjGakR3HxNrvjLnGGcYU1cQM9GT@1vo7H/PSi6/odOGFEtKL8XoVxAZmIeluj55tletphxiG1otUApffj29CESzFXXCUF6Ni8s4n@PvrrDeorllpD8DVcpz2JRd7mcWWkY4VC6bBjq1EEM7szkLNFZTGDElCWI5kcTmM56lpSsOjC5kG6yUQEmGOS9kK4lJj7SAvUET1zbPqhYjrn1ylfSmJSAqCjQ1UExVdrd0Y5NLr9Gql@5gCtasTGmK7Fa6gaYya4ESrsngVkQF1xHV@nmIYriK8MRffjU0ZRGQxdJVqVREvpp1iGuWudZ1FMs1vkSIu68F4VwbBYJub4x561LA8s3hpfEi2e8qYXjVOhgBW8zKwuxh7afvWOthBTLORS1rQxx7xc9nmNe1DNJVCf7HHLvApS7QoJOxgIDI2ijpQhSjhNggfGtrhETNW42yWxKfoUaZb6ppbbdc6uQOPWEQ6C8Q75kN4lHM8FoAFm4oJHKsWl0JYrt996O97gazdGZ8hSZp4MipUZrZ82oUoTP5bVbqRlmyKTgWNG@51s80UJOtpM17ENp5GuXSPQCBJQ1M6wadUe01MfDGAQxDJ4Vkc27qhsX6oTJ0/5Hs3wrHyldBKEALCE0lHaB8RrcQ8wSLhEDBlLRAKw/jCqBah3IU9pKKaiQuEmozlKx28JZs1YUGIT0rtEvHVnqJ5ywxrIqFVlNlIbLKhdUsB7NcojWDjo6CPhrCtZUqdg17sJgdGtC2XAoNYHGwnm4yw67M4aysWAIbmaxzMkahop9BFMORQcbJhJlznnSBCeFLQrxsKbBMtNQXFdofuICUSFfnSrEgguw1lUNSC00jxft8ojFfjB2q@jH8UDDENBfkQjghjqrTj6TQlH4qQvP4vIVIyaD390OlP2km7kqqcnX0TbTIe/F2i/dic@9Zxg20NuDug3/DPseaUnBjuv9Yq2YA8D3ef8lMAf8wgVK8QqID2YHbx4kr113fS/W6epx0@eZuzX5RjxOXu8EAtmNgthTZVAU9MSEfJMvAs3KwpSD3n7RhKiWduxdWCComgpLXzKR2qpdZpJgZ6q@KjCdMDSWU@B40R@5FFE2IR1fTPsemwwaF34cUmU56bYvVIlSIuOIx/pQQv3tDzpQ3lJXMI7BWu9KtjEHgoUGwjHU485M7iVjpkRw77OvL6/N0GNdL1vOfLpLdRS5bvbNcVl4lm/ZqKp6tliOQLdZ/Zhu/rZyWGmihHVtDbuNCJQM@qRyAYpigMXoYp8Z84VrmkdvPF/v@FF/@qBvD6h9efFnV6O9nhZjVVIjpFwoxaQGp1UfDG9XT5Yk9wLKdkIa8KmIP9zfN9gfrRvU3LeyPLwO30nJSeUrd4uuCbpPLqdTQhCodkv2xsCPktbymz2xZ22eWc31B83yn2/D6n9vwP/Y23NC4wISXt@w0xtT/Off/CHOPKRTHO82dZvdXO/fV72yTsOzceatl2fet1v4n2yeLp82Txe7Glz@Wk/J@u/HtDP4m5R/LWztlfoQH@LWufr0t75f3sNjWVXnZ8DwPHqWVgyNoZf8z3SaWWu7BP/ubqt2tZXm/5lH1D@X9LXhotdsAycni2e7JYqeJ/9udP5L4YZ6uaOHjplYjyqsiGwKfBYqLPKnl0zht8omxOzxHElDqeNZAijs/NFojgNF5ZtHeaYqsAgTE@R/eBnIF1EWAV3dp8xTlMEkojwZHXKj8D@Krx5VgBeguXPhDXdBuL6JXmnNCpZtAKSEF2jp7WN/Co@szSUOhAdCJJ0jMZFduUC8c6hhTbOHf/eYntk5M8ciWvBW26fEvZ5uyK@7Irvi/ZStaJufTSbsgsXrZegLTlQTWDzHDEk/CKAoSlvhHwSSALRmN6eEUBR286a2P9@KNwzfs/vdINW71qaHuD3GXY3O4oXq0tOwHj2FlhRekFb2DVame8Xxsa0P9AsaNd4ZhnIyKrhmFyfm8RznxX82Wz5MvKRNFA/NqJ5yVogGyXK9x4aPjAGWSj4HEoASwg9l80qC7xUBgw1gZTP9@4b8B0PA@UxjaoAvF0Nj/xqHLQ@MgohCXxXBo0009wXjwMoj8mc9Z09Brfu6PgueYGAYmIz63UXkqW19QcE1iZsfVyhJhHORwuZKpxhmsiPfHFRX@Sai1LAw3phtjbIxTFyZEvNuuU9QE1LI5tIBuqR5Op0lanqPGdQX6ma1BOcFgkjg0BA8H0xEBN8fxrykg1ixLXhAc6U/pNH1BHRE0MyvEmxxwVMFkfkG0o29WPW49OpW8aV7LuOGaPF53Hsmt5raNCMVpEmNzawe/zNn3ks4lS5I6QI8DBGuGBAryhMzptPACNIU4nvZ@oLw/yJVgQSL91dU3WfbkRg@PaOyeBCOfeMVlL0yowCCMqQDWbIzegezOKKpmSLU3H8V1XgsUWBHG8TzY3N7ZIIBox1dFB9N@pmi7AS3P/NmyQcCdJxdjPYrd5NwaB2@DsXivENiUUZYXJdEZXqrlz8fk1rLlEukAKjMjBSw4u1V@9/TZ0ecHr549rYKYsonFYwpL0mUdA7n8eY2@D8eYqYHJCKvw8q33tjaYyJ24WnmMFjkG/bGJ9jUTYNVAHNdxDwgjp@JRNfGz4IatCNX2yaiqj8Mvp7M3OnExLjcEZU63HdgKuWrll8sY0hVjX2UkwUxiA6iDA1OR27MxMJ5rhW7kFYAB4W7dBChyjPwTKdfeu1@r6TX1iJ5qwFhrtX02sthPxiEonpWv5pMMt63Q2vGtCjA5PP5n1na/Qnyhbnescw/1@E7fa3Z03N5bZ@6@17ciDxEKhxH3anq4VPPnzCUyzQaEuOTlrEIm/@e/K27nKk2iM3YSF7P/W@88lby4zkz9GV@X6lTiPkxWAtXe1ZNgkTzhbJNe0tEVetPBUq69fwJa9cB5Z/YROe572KvX1vqet@6@hy5nEWahjIAZBq@gRbeD74aZdzpErHFyMsE7kFcxdO@7F59/ClOOfmJBnBx/f7r6oFGtVFy3g0PwPYrve/rli7@ilX/m1snafzSbXgheZr7upA6zfREfN08J@qqNQ2vgKgTOOQoSGX18uHzlj74Aacmp@IACdEuiwDiYlHDPl/iyDvomocyF94OYOPLs7OTa7vuRR6XOZ8Gww7aKq9h764zcTgJ/zs0uNqELr92m1hOo5KFXUw7r4QR2609fvfjcq@z5FrbqFayKylpPEwcQChGMg68O8EakDOkAVyGqSjhajwgG/lur2PvZsew1/P1K5@rqRng@55yuIPxUUgIeOPOqUNzMuz6lnVlKBcso8PAFb21/efbKrkJdTMGCLye4vS2JaXEQq6f6YHJDTkFb4PIllvG8jZUVeodV5rHntZtNFzOiXEFrMV5hDs3ywpp1rma@N3A0Iv0oLLiwp11vNziQJW60ttrNze1PpjPYIjy8E30lBhbiodbyNkyWKyAbBp66/GcF5GTYTb37G6s7X4aH//zd7sutp06/91nLrto/xOS2P4tMAGb@ZZ3FIuCxM8n3SkBg5GLfb0T@m2ljY9Dsg@TZ2h4E25vBTnN9p78ZrO/2dnd3@8ONnd5gd9vf3uz3GphvnKrUL8IJSEk2kz92O7xbtzcJZjvt5u5w2GptbQ82d4e77eb6@kZvZ3PQ3NgY7rT89fWtQXunt9v7uNSWwlMCBqv4Lu4deQ788GbhrnSNt0tt9/8A)

I downloaded Opera 9.64 from [oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/opera).

This answer is based on [JS hack for Opera ≤ 9.64](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-3aedd37d5df858c460d27a0321a03370):

```js
var isOpera = /^function \(/.test([].sort);
```

```
             ""+[].sort
Chrome 75:   "function sort() { [native code] }"
Firefox 59:  "function sort() {\n    [native code]\n}"
IE6/11:      "\nfunction sort() {\n    [native code]\n}\n"
Opera 9.64:  "function () { [native code] }"
```

So Opera 9.64 can be separated with `!/r/.test([].sort)`. After that Chrome can be separated with `!/\n/.test([].sort)`. After that Firefox can be separated with `!/^\n/.test([].sort)`.
These Chrome and Firefox tests are shorter than former ones. Still need `documentMode` to separate IE6 from IE11.

Code in polyglot:

```html
<script>onload=function(  ){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=!/r/.test(f)?267:!/\n/.test  (f )?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
```

Spaces on line 149 are for Retina.

Haskell golf by Ørjan:

- `r$ f 0$ f 2 64` → `` r$0`f`f 2 64 ``
- `k=pure$ show(f pi)where f=id::a->a` → `k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi`

Comment: ``k=pure$ show(f pi)`` can be ``k _=show(f pi)``, or perhaps even ``k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi``, inlining `f`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thank you, that works.

Comment: I thought I was close to adding [GNU Pascal](http://www.gnu-pascal.de), but as it turns out clang, unlike gcc, doesn't allow garbage at the end of GNU line directive: [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMHGRldBXU9dwU4hTS@ZS9lQSclYwURDi0uPiys1OSNfQVdX193Z2QpIcaUnJyvoJoPUKRjZqRkiFDj7OPq5g5Uk5yTmpaMo@v8fAA). 
What a bummer. I also tried `//` (GNU Pascal supports it): `#1"..."3 4//...`, but it breaks Befunge-93 (division by zero at second `/`, can't be avoided). 
Both clang and gcc allow garbage at the end of standard `#line` directive, but COBOL prevents using it on the first line.

Comment: Bonus link: [format of GNU line directive](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/06f756bc/lib/Lex/PPDirectives.cpp#L1268-L1274).

Comment: It seems like you might leave out the `4`, in which case you could get Befunge to divide the ASCII code of the last character in the string by 3, avoiding zero.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Unfortunately, no – gcc ignores junk at the end only if it knows that directive is parsed in full, and it can be sure of this only if it ends in `4`. For C89 `//` is junk: [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMHGRldBXU9dwU4hTS@ZS9lQSclYQV@fS4@LKzU5I19BV1fX3dnZCkhxpScnK@gWl6TYJltYKugmg9QrGNmpGSJUOvs4@rmD1SbnJOaloyj6/x8A).

Comment: If it ignores junk, can we put extra numbers in the "junk" before the comment so we don't divide by zero?

Comment: @Potato44 Unfortunately, we can't – clang doesn't like it: [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMHGRldBXU9dwU4hTS@ZS9lQSclYwUTBUF@fS4@LKzU5I19BV1fX3dnZCkhxpScnK@gWl6TYJltYKugmg7QoGNmpGSJUOvs4@rmD1SbnJOaloyj6/x8A).

Answer (score 2):

## 283. [Zetaplex](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Zetaplex), 13260 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo  anet   /112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu1&&1Prers 6 4>80::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*s>Exps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody/'='d  Float#  +- $;#8;在91
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:   /          
 \?       -/!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<# /<+> /\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}} #@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,:1'<  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51 @!00:8:8 ;;~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print (171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~-<~ -<<<~-! `=> #
# 9//  >>END-IF*>>>* #
# '>+ /' 25  >[};]+ pppp^peeee*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2AAJVQIEECAIE2Gw2eS/v7W72NNm371wQjS4UCkA1gSp0VYEEms2OmfHurMbSeuXxWDGakXVH45VXWjnCWodtjdaSHSG9OhR@0g9ofWxsKDY0/2D2nJNZhQIIgOwZTcQ@bJGoys@TmSdPnjz5dbKpe92f/SyGD3vi9MadnuMz3/R81nKtc9NV2f0xu6dbXj63LkkYatftDPum7XslKcY0xmzzgh3ahtUCN@Y7Z6ZtvTFd8MsxNnCdjqv3md/VfbBYEIs9MHtv@299Zjj9vm63PAi5ztgTHTzbQ@OM6U3Pd3XDtxwbvDYYe2b39H6zpTMIYboD1/QJfJ4BCOOM4kz7FBh75Lieickbpuc56LjJ2LbZH/jjKliKEEJ3Lefh7uOPZyJvMfaxDjkb9MzRTF60LHtumW5rJoamsc9PDg5mXXPsM8Wx2cH1/Gnr7Jnr6T19Fv4G2x36zqE/655nux3T1llO3VJzs54Fdt/Vr0XZZK6pt9pWz1Qt22AK65q9gekydGFtx4Uq881eMVvMNnYnMVUD4xYnnjNgK8HDdLfjgadzboLRhJoYWGaLtV2nz3Tbu4CUtK3sJDyC3ZomBwMyCITGXnkQu2Uyz7YGA9PnnlBc0yVvSJn1LPtM4tT3xHVaQ8OyOxDOBLwOhj6VyZMMiFZlA0HDKhpYjLDAg0EWjp2@Ga0LD4gXcu0NTMNqWwZHjjnyTduD8noqs6DuLqxej7XMHkSYQDfSzHPY0Is4NXt6VzVUCZGLqbD@WY9ZzBgMGPeCYkCWDrJFZvadVxZ7A/69rsdGgz7zrD54@4bTbpsme2MOuhCd9VvMGBtSy5EYPMZgpnShbdWEMLYJJdx78nXAnY8otduQvRZrRsJBXijfVGrddgCFLrP1PqcIYzAmDACYMEbbcVR0bzmmZ8d9duG4Z6xpGjoWHRPzzE5bH/YgRauNVQK0YHms78AXKtJmkC2I7CM@EDYmJs0tCCYTVLE5gMaJVewgyUB9BzV94epAI64n6tK3@kAhlh/3mKl7FnItiOKZdouoYxDyMwdKG614dm5B4wNUDF2C7ZkukT/BZVgKAKmH9Jq4cC0fqAJLscuemLrLTlzTTHJaNT1DHyClRpOExBxMwceCqESc29vx/aODOBApj6HqAyBKd/3ka59KOlMrbLVRhl9FlsvS/uMH7HL1FM2cbwIhD9yEnmSVd8zLnJ6a8BtpzUzHvZIAqgRY6bGMM/AzujKADCo@ZDCjoxFNynlOHfQiCbPtmTqINB0eqgW1AYyAfZ6mkhlD10UOP0GqfgaF7jl2B/AJhXWHNq/yQhaqAOiv5aWZeW4iDfA6ci4IwyddoBD4h6AR7sI7HUIodDvQHAVGg3Q9pzekcBDT87FNAlYgKkI8bLPPWVu3ehgF/BEUz7VrekCcGGdot7Dm@5ZttlQWZIM4jwvt8RyS0wEoOUBr6Ef4C2UKAkNFOFRU9Hr/6z9sdToAZ9cwHLclyPVzIHaDukedMgsdHEOCdWy9R9mCcGlMnUeHBM71ntUiTqfbY5EEZYJSvXCGvRajhnphQZPr6sBwTWAShm9yIneGPuQxzfr6GeeKFqdcKHhfb0LFUgKUNhVbYff2oJYMaOZEM0p/6LeLTBnss7iXeZHYKSV2Vk5NyFxSTa6tZjKdMhCcukZOYIsvo5zPd6e6i89ZBwhlOMDytdJABMx2LgThaMo6kglxHkCX5U63V3NkGkPfxNoFlt@kkvT1MUWOsJc8wQDWc3J4hFUE9ej2HL0l6vg50ol3AYy1y5o6MHMfmTbiKZpTjA956yJvsT3oxMzXQ8gS8CTA0djvOnaOKQaTjYoDARLxqeLH03G3GU@q2NEkkmWrYqhty24l4tvQjKqAs3iybFSMmlWql2eiR/MAYC4QDHIaM2EkZWx9J5aDfKg36KIQAUFtbwBM1MWSGjqQg4c9lQ9yWpo1iVCpewNWQUzuwowDnpq6FxIGtTHehjC@gpxPQJi0iemmabYiLRNaNSDY966x156DXT7lCSsUeIGNieodEOsgMi/ILi8IT4lcpot0BtRhI7SmyYpK0wKqxvYDTFoQcaRsEHw9x8MANE71kRpFUoFuivf3kxaANa2zPrR3d8wME5kIcBOT9xCYyJAalAfCLHPaLKvk8vnpRnOtzfhuZlf5Erjum8zSpoGFj7YO5BysDbJzT7c7Q70DTcKxIYpuGObAF5wHSuL5wFtmOxByVERvqHpdafXebNrUKwQyzyQNaj9Ue6Jv05FdCFlcAUEL5Tku4LMWNEqDmsF06hDgfCZx@SUGmcrAS3lBFoIuHYiMt3Jo3EDAF10LWukF5c7mjI73KrPJg1M0dWDVSjtMGjOjVe/mJDUTOmE2FoJQsEavw4HeEkFVpxyo8qMOyyHrXn8OYCfMInD2iKua0VWgvRtg9h3bmQMUEBmCxSDTPrweQLQ6RkkXeqJAjqLGGoq/YRVBnQHXgJYP9Nf1/YFXAsZv@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@JpjJ0s65UmFArSS/TVjusMB4lssrZRUrR6MllbB1GsWYln42uJRFGBQSmMq5IfFZMpnWM7ETdBFEicnsYBqQI/NaPrErxROpdMhqiCfKC0ByOHRFy9LEL6zWQ9mYpD3GQ8DQPRSjwOmDEQCR4VGil/CkFHTz/jiNlLpSQiUBhj4@@aLAFuOISfjv5k@OYNMm4OoxlSWG@o8/HgQATIHNpBWBU9Z4bggVezzbATmUrjY6fNx3h7@Np/eCCZI6qtj48O9p9WKJmu7p2BQKV0MGzG80Gc0N2WCu2oN2yZ0rwwwDPBZExygrMhmHjHMJjiMAqmGDwTkb7SYAugAaPFKQHVYUqvP10Erwv53ZsqAwEhd4q5THgzgizx4HPzFCZ5AN3V3vHDqUm//hkIU8zwejj5obi8AGDNrHHHFn1iwA51z7FaJXZII04bpGugLRCuW@HMhu3YCnYEweDUiSbEp3cgBLmhqIlilDUVBgG3rREM8GM4O4SyHw7AgISAgQHCbBhqm@pzYm4yAyaJ828wEps3FHrCpUjV8CatE0Y7YBz0dANY@DS4U5mdAkDgQJnMfJ9k@RpgGBlNDYxoVuKmMoIcaeg24q9l0ah7aHldRC8MpLALdNuAVRxy41iSsHbIDBDxO4Bpc2SJvgha@DFG@UT3Ekkci@7yQRZSGQ4QMFPBXCRJ745hDF0TBgroyyd/2L59brmOjUhW9wE0sKIy1sEM8HnoBTLa3T3MPViM33nAAWPXnLUIbqNQZ5FreNC6bKfndBy2BgGQNFWVE/ahjXO20Gn7@gBalPWGELTbcezxDA2aZjgLXFhHkuczUxgyQ@HVV9ALsPmFngRYUObjwy/3obfW8tks5D@wZekJCxmBMltGdDTYJIBY1@gh3WBNfmkOumN3ipw8R8wC@TQVSg2Tz8vpID9DrkQLf0NRo42cu0A7D7xagWle2fdpQIRTkYPxgtJPCR@82UAJYzPO6BqgYgrotQqf1C8yrtPMFN8Kqu5cafcdX898rgKLxpeEwwPFYrKXia/EM4qCb5m8WK7KMi3zPINcagJ5tI8zNXNgj0zTyKAvdm4sMMxFT@C5ADWn8Nj0gmLyb4CDMOZs@TupFDJ2yl2YNs80dPIn3aEpmUbXYfIpjK@iJZOhg@haLVMBzIP0i4OyMJpY45J8Zwhj2pbZs/qWf0irED0bB24qMW8VuZbw3QN@MwHwxDJhNMJnWyadDK4UTPoou8PDPwVOTlA9n6kcpa7ZyqxNoD1yHLeLU1saTajkQtT3hUfG8QYt1R8BAB5rn/p3L@jnHx892G882T35pJIZem6mZzWBR7TMRh9G8j1oDgsezBvOd@4D7Vi207egRAHIN2e9p47jc@EBl0Ju98QwYgDj4YPGw8P7T3effl1kjnp0qz/s6ZjH0upMgBDGMYVZCsZwmg7IFvZwISQQLo7uHz0MoHz67OHhbuPB/pOjkwiYV8OepWujzOCss6hAn2IQpqlZjvqjXmt6jYrG6FNTKILZ4ICzzGBgzhQF3gq68URxSKqiB4rI2D0qCs5p6zhr77Kclt3aajX1YtEstIyNjc223m61NnJaMd8u5nP5LLw2C1sme0vBFcUc0bQVmPiUEM6eYRqQefpo6kYg4cA43ACJZTw3X6HvkswZ@by5ubGlbxlbW1t6brO1rueKm6ZZ2GxvZLNmQcu2m0WtuL40c5FsoGg1sfVp@gtaHc6UkCcwvwR8ppoDzzzIeheslcvlCka@vbWea@WzG63mVjZfbDW1Tb25ZWbbG@taTmsZOa0UxAUeC4wh04UKQ6nSBtE08FI08ExKQWcarWJaNw0W1gXDWV1HFjMIFsZx4CA8NtBjKJbFAWbgnkf3YFEc56eEewHd@7gkPpFkyRo6ioBFCogr46rbDBy30DFcE59aLQZWKfjnPP/FkQTkSy17hcAvcFU9Ur5LTSP3c7/dnnLOkfOZgl1Zb@K8Ts58TX16NVsU9prX3MAhvA2Cx9fi58K75jU3cAgvz@HhGv58cDM@84KGwAoEDNf858Ka8ZgTMIS0SZCi@wQmfkXyW7RJQKQ113thpBD2FsHm6/@NV14DRe2GWP5HauYN5AQksYcOyM8PLVy0aE@1GCkcgZ9KcjCNMD2Lhj5cdsmcz4zslHM5Go@3fcs@c2icHJoaWVXLY3sOY/fPetdjtmFkQa@poGEeAjlmQe68frNNrzkBsI@dnYUkD5riFT099Kx65il9cLJ3Xg6mp62nkm@a7SEMejJNy0bzDcGUrSKFbDeb1qKggAncPRF85wQrsadDGHjm1A1VC0a5uEwELJrPOZ8cHlHApk5jtum1DjaFfH/o@hBLfP/rN1pQCderqKuPaegXGhq2eYHVpbQX1piIihZ6za/dSSdPiCHTTSANHdeL9V5omA@aal9RurrbxxGWqG4gUHwBJSyhNZ5zPvUSfOcnUmKE5Ok1FWZbfWZc20vjOw7zYNg8qZuZlSCeLg2vcRGWMMIHwZZJkVysd14j5ogPByOiDvQ5c3I4m79gwYZNtjz43aE/5G/c5XBTjVoD/C1rrSJkNq83NROEY71pmUvq39XPhi1HARmPiowZK8wJOyk9TdMp7Z5@xo0NNM4vPi@ga3U6IEmI76JgF10Y1dBwNHNBn5tIxLOH3kBpQmX50IbIRq2ivyQFt8ffi4JYYi9gaFiMNatHr1tUekhcRC4gzBGicXuWEkGaNYPmnt4c4yC9@@FUhgmSaAPsp2KkUtl17PDCJe/olqrF8bGXpPhbW/Nj841hHCXzBlYZviFM4VPHVGaxReyGioU@zOrrPSXXihgXMvdg0nhimhOUZmwUo6d7QFq@qA7zHKqPXsvIHTspAwZc7sS0hNgn2Ql2PixaRBccTLRqw@lZHjbt3iJmOrvuOEkTt@bRKzIZbc1DbIukJa@rhKb5fMExfFzBXkBot@ByfPEYl@cjlKM6i5BmOBf4WyhldJ1zk7/n93lv5ubqFhxL6RFJWMbczqV1vRcBJ97F0zyrB8I/EBPNtmo01OW7NYLtCfnC4PX1WsC9UPSaj/yzuYXxjd5c9@mGE8yIRMdzt2wMntVzPHZM72W4hIJ5Hn/PbwZRtFu6rdDyUdQ8P5rI1ICpYlJ2ATHovY7TKxQ7GR1eCylm6LaxIxHf27LMkOVp2s0sL5CvHFsT34V9xVnGPbup7mglw8UNDhHjkm57Ht8Ta5iLCwgkiruW5hfuIFukmGqGD68XVYBrdC/0cfD9ObqjRdgNuqPBmOR1EB8xwlYRDL7LZfifJ7WN5am1bsfTroHdvKkQkco965nQ@9H7WpWyXFb7wBhaNnt7DtfuDc2hOZfBHTVfmbjBf8ko5vaZyopirIrJUZxAwqnRMNQbMf68Va6x40fbUgYDzBYa@Y3i0Vx@NwDBfoAj9CdgeIKG6xE79nAwVblTo0D76XLMdQdBy3ZaU5lEnw/lSMWbhbAp6d8z6bd0cMYHk7gUVtnIZrNCKIpMd09Zlg3a1sO4ryz@nkqYXCYpT8Jiz@lGjPPTmMy8QtVbZ56Cc6C34065RTMKFHhrK2NbtumP8X1LRtt0nN6H1B7w25aF8h5IsbhEdFMtXpOlxKY5Npk28XDSpdleNGHC@yIxmgXE4Zh9GSFEJ2lvVcMKCjfQQDsz1uVTSJEp35tSgR6e5qX4JoveYkFVTMZoalHdXNoYufjrNM2ezj@jwsYyeFvq@lJ4obQi5GpaBcOVM75WNll7jc2wrMEYkGW1YFDUNfsmWZeMJvTWq6EXfBYGGjn4m@Ot0srkongDC3iEje@pdbmIFOU7NgzjfN3tmDgO6uH6uXBdxJeD@fe5yD3s6x2TnylbxjgnUyO4w5qPHifG@ZMkJb4/zYBofJPIclKAxnRmjr3gOxfgo7EB9Tns3zzLN9PuDdrSdFNDVzNzlx1uEBPtrtO1u2aX7xkKbYuaB1Ckz08DLisE5L/TNRjxp@h@pihme06vdxvMIn/k3NJx2nPztI9n1FoQ9YPgjvUmeIjPjbOH0M0Tgqi/X9RuuuYQeivP8Z2BqZBtUdAeTi7x9yIuGiwD/byzVktnFAAjwffnhW/cFLGjO/5gQJ/GoDf06EVRFTpauGTIxqfOKUmiS@a4HfWN02@qwlE94N9HUOELmE0Tz7ngFiZO2WbHaRpd66ZMN03dt62zTDDHxK1Lh72DCJ4spjxAZ7VnAXrdsYr0Uon6H@PncFGli@kq3rGFhvlUUGJ7Q9cdI6UHc9E0ZUBbsiZnlidcZXp/RjhZzJc70LAoV2LlcY43yRC4cy/YobZkzUUsVC4kS5LaUUJXzCyIOdrCeaup7aORNrW@zl@LpKmZ8lOmIuvDHzLxKrZV0BSkFZkfBvcpmppa7J7bxdndYce7ziT5skALBDN8za393Q6eAr9F5fOKhr5Mt8VnUR3kehncLw/fBtTm0Fy6xJNfusZD4bSeojsWfBrwgXodLpyw61kDj7@Z0s7NFT2uL1tfDzWeP/YWddYy23wVBk03yYx9x8VTWyCcKIZregZO4iNv55IY52O20wEer/TYJHAQdm4Rrq@UzyWJsO9UvnhsdnTc0vnQwt2dvTmUAlBnF8xvAvq1oe5ZXxs6vjkX3uyi@U3gHukdy/hkCvMBsACjYt8f/0w1BXS6jvyLruXRgZnAsGTiComMky3SWQNGDvOGfDMLBeHx8uVzMxGRS@w3Z8ohC/alhwZcqkB/fW5a89YAnAENPsdkWjb9b/k0vSu@c6lq/saDZclfDPuDoSc@81OnvUHRyfH@Gbl7FxawSuU1cGjW1Xv@/An0yPQuSG@iM50YF8nzX1o9p8O@LGYZCHsgvKF4P4fg7kO3/kT3oUXYcwiY0l7Ay2eXaHHmROFc0nsNNGGuM8WyLX/5LJHv6zDaCr5YGN4B4bHPzEN8q/c@FIJyMh8jD5dKsiADjI0eqhXg@@481nRN6EK5MoNwi9zyzswAWjymw/9oDPUPRKlfJGbuBasVot@xzYvo@G/polMJO1vHHvoKni9Yupw@6WQKSzuZEhsVCxFaYYmv7T96loySDO3BvUnENWGMOfR644lp4XaIGUq0bJDyFjPn6dDBQOWBSVointJu0Rvi7A7w/Br1AQ@ceYOpJ2PX9G89GoMeZdh/YBq4CHpj2o@dRyDfQd82AC7cf2ry42lTzGV@RIz20DH0HuCndWMyxwR2TucxGbfrA7MJ9dubmOYLbPMAP9B9fYGARdORNLgMTTfSitVrmu4rmmeMmBeNl6cz9Ik5ooHLYoLhDVLxDYNL5TjjN9VcZleMvIHj2PxNXDkLH@3Rcu4D/QW9br/4r@Im6qnucO74b7q0R6H6AX50clFxXbPp9Pgbi7CgJ7Qtvs9Bdy3Tyzy07OGI3AobTAFxbv4Iie8mzqqbpAIGGlKwxBpuM8Zdc4J3zgzDQE4@1z3agTB/8DO1pfn2@526ums4uConDB@4Jhc5m3YDWw/3bPOdEk2omBEwNd0YilNON2W112/26bVw8BKp7admE8/@Nelsqq@P5kmW02fYhOPMKbKArWHjL7DEExgeJW@eMZsd201j3BrQi5j6xVxCCZJ7bJnGGz15q3FVpEXRlHVGpyHw3EY1vU0PZKCeqfhd3PSZ8ZfNpQfng@csyAz7Jq6BT68ELSQlx@sSHTjzV/1DVuuaYuc47lqERh@Ykd8quwsJFcHD/9H9TzPQJTcKG6g9YThSOsDIbt5nAJkfurb43IbYnjie37ZGRwPUi@W4izgLFisPUeDDGwGa1hYVAmrPHvb4dEgnsq2s36KhHgiGbQdMPWLevqmY9rlC@qJG10vkuKTyJrOLCtd8s6WICRJc1lAeBnJZGEx856zlRtkk7mrVMhyxo8KG2Oc6D7kXXrgqCR7KwKNvZuA9OXx4dKIOPG1uKwimMXG34tDq4SojNbjADRBDpmvSW0@nxrFLnqR7aOrcW66YjcyYvdLdyHIt36GH5xIz9481Ze/hoYoBFtQRX3JR4IPLiVOfxRs8Bl29afp6Rl84zEJf058vYn5y8uhhanJOmyX2uq7TN5NR773j4zRwKPbp8VzvaOwDaFFtZ7Qw@uG@piXnkPwzm5Y0FzHXOSktgnRiwmAZKuwTfmT4RvHMcAZm62Q8MD@HvhcZvHfL5AsLC/lYP7c62HLZ1kJEUeNmW2phIxnZvm66qJ4s@C6qzzNrgBzWoE@GfxbupkHBYz3jrs8XPpZtWJgVglhWbKT4sEha9jq1@pYCLaPTRVNG937RjGmatgjPx3ob6pXlF1bWdIB5gknPOb/Fcrcphj9K6KT4QFWKdeM@@02lD@w@gy9cPRCOYGwu3MWzDEDoXJjb4C9Me6zbCtcjsHTwPcDedHmQL82b18vEyUVSGRfqIgIOys/UgpvlCqUlnhroPxQHkEmMC8b54KgbxhCnpqFpqYwCJhJ6KpVMSiLWJyDQ9FG5Gkby6Bw9NJYyywZGzGUXeikKj2pUEmxVZ9sVCJFMlrk@IuC20PMMzTJrWwFg6Omsjg0ZCNIn3XDYK3CdIB7rAY8PoNZqbPVyVMqWtCtUUVKSWb3O84sPJbI/GpBit6c8em1Vr1dW44oSX42f2iWWjYfBzZ5nzg@uT4WFzOJHZDjELlf66JDGxhCXZa5GC4RT1DnX1e0WcBDBg6H8LlcGxTWNneBxiz//vZZQxUcqJ/uWp/cAIahRE7qDrnOxw9MN0DUY6C7pVSNlTz2uh0rZ2xUa2rgGPqisZwcnRaEGTKjvBMsTvnYR5oLTDW67wFP9PicLnpvwhLZIOIwVFMpwesO@DcOilt/1VHZs0YH9oTs5gieUmtq@i2urrTQ7ZC0Tt7OTHgbaStBznLNQUP7z3@PKz0gbgzglHyRPWgwjKaLSBY00jhmGM4RcB0DemK4jgiQQybrhD3HPDinRJPck6iggrWxA60qgk4yS4YrJ9naPmbLP4qhaBzXjlK12YnX36cef17L1yjvWz5j/9RuZ5KVAnPwRMARPTrMgSPkKCSvqnQfviW@cyasjmScYqqqwxFzMBa8PVC3KiQy1VQQ05jiDoNng4J70IobUKNQTJdBM9Rzs/u2TqkAiWPOClJPRmWgbJUfScepBAwNrkkDzVldZTQz5XhLl2Gd5SBAVvOlcVaCDqkGtvomKtjDK6oi9ZSTCQf@h5bNg44jsoW63fuV@wDfXo8fPMg/M5pAOYpzn1Fy@QsVZbVS2q2SCMYSDShNrL05HuaxyOtrcr2e8AKmnp6OPsrkvAOuOC7HuZrDl7T9@cLmqVrNv33r6mMnyVbzMj8sBm1i9fHL4ZP/4ZPfk2THUwlXA2A74odmA1yAV0Tn4rtMjdZSAF5w4@AD@E9omTBCVHieTUvTEMgUVuJYVeZUbI6xpKvYN0efF98yI//UAgqdBvyaF/QJQgU7EhljDwnOlk0zEFXoEicosn2R3Vw0Rg4cS5/BSQpXMKoAsBZB1S1SxxYXd4W63wdiNUJajbWduEMRYmF4t9OdFnIuCq3@Qcg90z/vFy82hLC83hVlSbggaugZxDnYPHz57uj8dLejkietWtvLiqD5nztjS@BREoDiRNOSIiLgXpyIzmSJwq@jMuD5m078woViCORp9HpkolPIvSxPCBMxUUC14XUghiQTlAKUbFERmNQm0rVEki0EfHQF3yYsYMoEDOQQdZFyVBeQYqbdW8QmKgVAFuoKm94SYuODXcS8q/qSDFodFwz566PE2t6CrCnsdj8F/pFcKTLk6GzHRnWl1prAc/Hqm3YECB2GTZd5HsVWOCHmV510O84sqiSFPrVc6LVrTYFycwIdeuqcPvEAUjLHHjm@W2OuhQ1p@AmYSyhekDVvnWsSparlebNIeBGNWEHyDfovgHR4cV1A646IZ8fcozQ1t7KggEFfmLfRw@C4qvucKErhWXY5yR@h7DbpKmuP1hH7HUErw2LnlWTCApUpoo4zTA06JpREFR6XwpN@J7fY8kEla0H2DhOJjVwvCiUrHtvnZbcVmcgxoUg1FxjSTJQzrVa7r/4Su9AJH1C955FUKR5C9CMz49oqiAOY6lh1ogC@hSnia3iwx3x3iNutq/FqUIAslMildv9@LBJyj2vjUzLz/9R9ydcanPpi/I8yj7H2w/aqwtcH8a4GPpoHtn4W2HNi@y20vMlhl11W@TvI50R288KQ7UOc9WYrNFg1ZQ6ANn4oUVjpW@OeHT5hnoAZkrNK@PorUFjKaYKTCrD7QxjlVNQbnKUxqcgInUfscKAXIC8gEpRwUbCg9060nUP9nKZPBnONqtko73s0R32hG6kBfD1GvNchimUK@sKFlIJPKeQCQlHR18NQuB5hMloA1SufWoPKyabDt7W0me4beMyuFMieRzKr@Yl1@GWZ0FcJKfLxQYxAHokxigF9VREus6iktiVGxP4trcWRtLYdTHAiFCTJAkCQ624FaH5A6HYEqIGcbRuwkOI2DcRDwbduJaJwOACkAiMPmupqnW@XkJC6utkTaqRqtBvk5BjvGYCV5Hs3WXrBT/9SuCy3cDOjvR3Mo2AbzP5mjmpvTIaotu65COjGrABpLw@4d2w4uXB1Ablkil8mtZ7RCMtL4ZAEK8ost/i2AhDYOPMMwrVfOwNvd2z/89OjJ8TVtehQyPhsszuLV7dSpoqZr9dAQD/M9jdT7B5njR/cPAlRGczWZcsEQk2MGs9mcl9psThek/pwfer6eNnlcS0jL3hYw7eFVDuikznXoE99MJOAeP3N5LdVE8vKqVt@untqxa8m/nafvPaauIXGB6dQjbe/x2WxiFsP7XU7wfhdPDXR5aKjIA895@87ZRC2IcIh48OABFOAAkpoJQi1in5CBIz4DNNFfleMXzHjE@vgsESntDnMUCXkSXEWDTWuiblXoGe3qXrdnNSXowluoeJhrCQvUYIX6xVRv0LP8RFISqmlBmEC1sOJCmlFppNIWmEQSmznBSrNlqksDeEkJGgHAiz8Zel32xBlE5rYemIHpKcgj7MGQb4cw2afDPoRr0@epSfPBIKEoEBkQFQ@zysfV0LKE5tJRCrXDQno11F8qCq72W/nEKKl2zVHL6gADTyTT0NI/0kCwCnWrYKFJm6kdBx7HMfwxHluNovSDFNiOJsD1mq5adsscJVAjW6kOEiq6xy@en8eBpc7SAGnR3Qv0bs6o0w0aou6LFjFRRTvT2LbCW2hm1BJvbaFWuz7urq4wSPHYdx@CEfqnRLuvD1hiSEquPaYysiZOE3ba890kU6pcVZTNUikaV8OHPEBuxqBtMhHhsATOQyYyFagddPXsFn7eWANW01S1DmZKJMlWcU5tD7pynI1KSjBOgiglAlvBumUlzBGnXpVTHsRBf4kUTzLU9DzHm9QT01KHg7igUrPq3YjCvkkL5Fjd2iqJ2phmNVsMyOI6l1czAHYOCwnkVMCv0P0BWMPLSPDWGlx1BbZw7zPTtk1AENBMX4c@WB8CkbnJdHADVXpyeQUXsXgWPxHKRCCj05da7Mcve7gpZzVTpumZ8hX0qS9PsVNti251nPnvM2qmfJlY7VXGGRB0ktXEareipdbXUqlVey2xamNXf/cuzupcrYIk0VBhkDSCQMpqL1kGegbJo7Jql1f17cRqq5JboxhghWHaJUR452XUy1X9KrN6F3rqNLi4vPEmVj3SJJxVVe0K8octZDWTBpq5RMWrdP0UJr9qpVKYB3W1gRl4lzk9ThHPPj3O0ARSWcijmU5fNLcZrhrWxLXLtzgChbOoaGDsOWTs4kxWIwiMupmCBfk5fgtkD57wZ7hOw2hJ2PSiAwB52uf2jEXwuzgpeeR6m7kqZ0DgKAFIRGtaTyaBmfzsZzGtwOTE6k5hvXeeiuezZXhp5TzLs49WTxUlt1qLsdi91bqu@w0YumfWLk8fFDvnzGznCq9rVlt9Xaw8SZ/Vnzz54l3j3YvROHmaiMf2jt7K2gaE32Rb9Lvts8lyC55bqkGMrWWkWGZNu7uZybx8@RKEXnxqVbUaBFHr794la/F6bRPLtAhQPJHLJY8ty8qw04HXasGv7HQZXQhXj/EnlUoo5AIvpcbddnb6ozYaRrtmpzPc18fc3YoN8XPgi7iPvnz@/DkantPD3jzl7izGITIRrtTQ8zGWy@b@/CcrV@nLJ43tP/9mP2Ou4OcIP9@5eoTmYy3/0crKR/fvb2ykAVvc/OTLJ1/f3d3deJDOP6nldzaU7Mr2n/3pykout53LrNQ9T6vHa2dfyLnshqz@@Y/jjSdPvuZ5WGH4rDMNjPguwk9j@Tw7Y2/gOWsz/Cfzm1bErKO52X7DYm9imqbFxvTXwJUGHFpXiPlMPytMq@5s/rfvHb2O@bFqLvPcha8fex0rFGPcCAawrQe281g1to3BClexcaZSqYBx87/9W4hf/RTgoM94G17VfACrMI5VlQpFeRurFsCg5XKQ7v/9jW9M5@VeDR55YzMn79ThWaNnW4pVR@BZrR4esFw1tyYISSve1e5GItt@F0SR05hW3Di6R1bLdOhr41e3YdAK7UfTcqecUDnd8C/OqcQmzl3AHtQ6c2LTQcksXCD88xhREJAQURE3CwciLO7wfDbc81NdX9tMbeTu2eXn4gkNv7znKd5oWFi59/JBJrNdBWkAn1Lp3mnQCDNssyg7zj2cImQjRHqZPQwRXJWzxZycTqfvYfiRgs8oNsEg40hisSnUxtjExqJOMRZEY5MwHxpuH5@/@Pd/8f2/@B79fZ9@/0mKBdvqlNp5vRo8QENy1ZUvT4V1NPUAk6o/ZVr247fx/Hr8GEzQhLTQd1KiWKxaxRf9CxuZ6DvjJnyqoYVCTKLMD8cEIwqQGpNi7zIZhlXCzoPi3FsprRRLhVIu02AzJbkH1STnNrfkejWXzx1B1WkyVdxWJBRA34FnBf7oH57Qiu8VchHOFOT6s8Kqt35mWbwUq8Vq9Tpv3NVoLd30PFWVMlCfSpZGtOSxcymmAFNLpZ4CcTNB5PCcpm58nqVUtSHMaHDg6yiKA1Cl2C/hqUosdglP/d1a7d1akHKtKgzbSr2aEhmCj9q4V08pV1c19UWqXBb/IDmWQxs@8GHwg4LUrxRl@wUAq02DjW848YJzD6Fz4PRWGy@2AXxqu7ZdcfbopzYQu0r9RbW2PQ1CZO7evZQKtXAPAFRX6ywJYqmirNQWlgEA1hMMhjZQx1fbV9Wr2vbV1fY2/G/T@0p8wfVq@9o/fSbPgjAT/zpS1WktUz3NiPZerYNdzVTRRc2cgqEKXwgHvY4Uu0SCZLW6gkOtilLTCvk6SRfsEXvEH9uGf/gFVnRBh0foZvOXzUMEYUJn7iLF1oDNZkraWm49kx99VNjPAa/yMOmcLGfW0PAW@34Q2bakGI6DtvhwaIscXr7/6n/H3@n7r/4ArFBOvBiWfJuv8e/hG/x77ePfiYF/T1/jHzt5g39Pffx71MS/Jx7@nbzGv90m/p308e/@a/x75OPfsw7@SbEKYyCjru5ke9nzrHamnYHBYlkYInSzXa0FfJJlTZYdZ8cs23e0FphM@MuCycq2WbbDsnbW1jTwBIPPsj6a2vDpwF8boLjwZ2WzCDx7ziCVHnJfUp1P37cNljyVaiz@0gSxUtXUrFqwGnVUwwWyZDmWOT3NcGmb5TbKpMLr6oo1GvuPHzQaGWy/p4@co8n/0VE/al363z9yHh05fQf@j46OHp0CJ66m7qWUe/BUqqlt8dmJVcs7pyUF6T1oWrHM9s5pdV1BcyEFrSWHbqkPfCYQ4VtdOZXiF9CfX5RJbChfnJcvymQIrdzQEAFEMG6AWGUhboALxDt9niHx4AKec4JLNjRegGdg4obM84tTFJdhgBT@Azqi1n@Af@v/W/@PnrFErZ6ENnB5tZ2gJ4l/yeTl1eWVeFeTiYSwJLbhDx3AjlEur6popECXYKolkvXk1RV3g3ciuc0BVjGN7SpFngQEzhQL06R0@SvxD/vFtMVzGi@DxFxZTYilz9PTUTabLDfBJVz90N/SKlqyTPuLVps1rf5nP8ZZFG0nSYHyG@WytsbNuY1cubwhLJvFcrkozKuJxNb1p5rd0Qog2GxsJJPlMlh2AphZsAYwiwBTmPMA0vR0o4ztvhxLYv45M0hkcUqW7k2KyyX57t2EuGZsZzBI3r2rbWXfvg2dGo2W5TYa6L7@9q3ckHF3UmUrD/Zs8e1b4EPxpOMmHjt8XTyhaOyjXJVS2HJcKOUmeDMtk5uk2dU93ffdxBtrkJZxu7onJ@mug2zWcU/jP/3uN795Gq/gfhVy3dAQAKbC8tvbhY1qtbAB5kIRECGv8g1QiU5qS0terWZkXlwmr8ZjwksrbibJ9SqO/iy2zXaq0Hg9fNjlVYyqlG3kk4nm2Exegkvgpm1tcUe2UUgUU1vir7KSZNU1Jv5whLae2ljbXLuHQ7TR/AfZbflSr8QzmfhV5VIv4QTeVdkQN@vgyVL97t31LUBpMVs@lRqNB7snuw28Yhg3KEA/zNCReLeEi88DN16j2db8Vr2GxaufxuOl8j2qfK2YZ7F4WYRT4tANsOIW7wNinidZbTxjPiKwM7@12IBpm@vQK0OnLA1os9hmlrVwvd1lTru9Ao5QhayJWyM8s9cLriO6cNxe68JqmStS7MnD3b39k3RuG@SF3MHuXjp3/Ox@TENrfmIn73W0P93ffXD0DCI8ebi/e7z/8eHn@8@egLsnvXLf6Kapm0PTbFwMhxev2SvLaliAvd7QsizHcCETDdM0BxAseMqmyUzD8vRXr3R3QA/jjPz9j779/kf/w/vf@e773/n2@9/5/k@/@v634fd78Psu/37332zl8f3Tr/7Z777/7d8Bx/8Evz@G309@@tVvfoP/yP4n8PsvEbc/Eb9IOP6TANav/vSr7/34p1/92g/g9y/F7wfXf7/@k/m/739r8Q/jfe93l4f57r@F3@9zWEHY7/42d8PvtfC/zcP92g/e/8a/4/9/Jv7Q@Dvvf@NP8CUs//QHf/Zf3n/zP@RyxT/71@@//d333/re@2998/23vvP@W/849/43/7WWjb5@9/33//Cv/@j3//qP/hf6/z16//5t/t//4J/@5f/xl//xL/9I/H4Cv38Hpp/85X8A0v27P/wR/n/vD//uj3@E///bv/q7P/wXf/er/ysZfsgN/8@//Df8/Te//p//9re@89c/@cbf/ouf/O0P//Cv/89f@79@8z//zf/4B3/zP38THX/4k7/@41/9q29@@6@@9c//6ptfLXh/e@n7q1u4f/VLcLl9Pm8D5zbl@lCXr36u/Pwi2JikAnRC9wmxHIjE98cmK0tZlmX8Be30@//k/W/@CpD/b0BAsP1PYIN/bgGv75CFffEF8saoP0vR5I@S@uIL9BfD@S/AFqvSnB32EsVcMbUGUvLa1lY4mbc9AfMdiPE2A7J99t5bAPEFxecP@yIIBnn7LQoG4ZgIFoSbziSFwV2y3P2nX/3zH5NHGBedf2UKZDZwjoZexeBvA3R8B3nDpLjR0N9B9vL@R994/@N//P5HP3z/o1/F/kTZ2ErvpkEqWD5HDgHztwiHAQu3CQcBNRzzshW2IuXAsLKNM7uSlnr5EnK/AiYYwK1J@XWwSVqVzBqaIWIKbIxP@KXwDf/SxhZDC7iMyBW@LAVe91OsUqmkpFEFpwcxKFgxzohVizgHhfMtFYCLkXicdKMIYyM2uk9QIGYl9ZQ11iojHjGFDlWCgHQlodNTWcvJqWLlASRYGT1gCAuBp6SX8H1ZqRYroyqCe0dZABip@5AkhKpg7kbVd2CvEEwIL40evIOsFCupVLUILhUsZIpSSzcoTS1PhaOyp1hKTH3CF3er7txj7CNZK8p8khRQyURofKcmoTEgBAf/09SaKA79B0b6rWF8qKcR4Ye7cf8ddKb4IgDAVRTc5Ag/RcHc3APvEQeVomThk@IQAHMpPgPGQgcSclJSiuo3RRZIH/LwwQ@A3K5KvECrq6sSWuV1uXEEg1IY/blnJc/XXVyEJSm0xOTClozOuGMsKCBuLVx9QmPYtQdr8Nbgf3@F9oFTmcpr0mocZ1/iTKT6UYr/7t1bYx8BDug7cZOYklp3NpwYL@52KiXnIOGqA7Y1KmqKAOH8Bf2npBcxicWIBqDRpPkbPmqF3BkM70V@yeFFRcKc5dY1tONs7HA4xBiqmlbTafFV6UsOqjCo5Cu@6ipJm/ywag/PiATzFFsSH2ExrbBBB4TohsckS0oxw0QxjkmPvM59ZwTDmLQsp7UCruQlxZTRSSmHrVjaL2Xh/XWnVKq80zY2JfiSfYg3TYqzn0BPXdM11e1tpIvqpUKTZGgE@bcgVatiPwPTpOrx/gkEPzliWi6rMhgCXW5s5jbyG/nceqGQ38xpG4WtjUK@uA4ct5DN53La1sbGVnFr82o@d7qXTsubBXm7@o@uPf/dP5r3zHfFR6p@wUYqLkwoV1K1V@GbbFdxm4N8mpXLNHdHKF2tZdP4l1tfhzdkOa3lN@srK71LBTFwSjs7L3EjCeRaulQYjBjvwMOkOxK7A07wQBq40MvE1pzDo7LYhoEXZ/OtGLKWB0qHKjkFUufgpEH0KU/ZBkAJl5eXkZ8UW/nyS59VqzDYUQ4PpBi04S4LdiUoVkvtqnS9c2vomuTbYaxlfW7hHTZqy/IGPX0MFJpVpdjV1VU7XCcjK4/RwveVQS5NMF@NdOn/f355Ty6n5NaVdU3R1vH/BkMO/28fPgf/OXxDrPWctM3VOFXxmldHb1XCq9BZInnZqrQcgw6OlduVWl3FA/Dlltp0WmPV88cwFBcEVIk3e45xFg88LbwfDk@fVjJ6Rm00gAJ9B8bnNKLfyW3mSysZN6PipvpEmyV3coVNcDm1AydwyaPLi2mnrVJLDXL0CNoKxMuVcoX81bbQ8liF8mC@qpiLS5G5ku3Y5hVupC7pbeChlwbfflSSc/miXK6VJ3ZgM@X61b2@2bJ0dprFc3uXcyMWCvJVEA6SxtE9zr@wRB/vdMId@qXsaTa5IHIWIkOWKafStlAdVaUNJTVghnW82bZW3w6USlWld@/ejWgPV@nQ9sVmrtxGEd2ZhNMJd0HkuqtxY74wMWbReIIKwB5D3QELt9lDPJXhO@zE4bv/75vGghB7XZ0u@t1zHc/7BcLc1@0z7vXA4oqHQq9PdLzPwOtbfndBiGeDPh60Nd1fGoT9fhMyiDTFA9yHl9tznHkBNtmzJwtK@ShUHIj7vkhzIAR/evjxJyeR78n@7t4nUoHdP3r8YOaTF4Hy7OH@wUlo3eS@QdR8COLr@w8fzlrFB@SFMk18rbD8Ju77Diwa031dlmtsVC/HAC3@FUjX5ZY91O7e1Z64eLCiwDaqxWypdJotX0FxKvfPSgPcPe6ZgzWvuj8aeFsbUEI2ZM8A5xdl1H0jy9AOD3b3sNll4pU4tATSjoSSlcJWy7Fi@W9@6/e2NOkR7jff0vjxScuT6Awz3iWL90b7EqomajkXNp0MbfaGJhsO2EJH@KATGl2r0/WZf@EEAaSmrjP4fegD8c3o4y938Hka5HbNpzcnOG5vstosK6kkwuW2ivni1nqumC5uFTfyWiGfT2u5tLZZ3NwCsSOrFbVCMb@lpYsbW@sbICaBb35rU4qBuGC1MxmQTTVZhm8JwNoG3oe2jRfLOWq3KsX4vDR7k9CTLKaH9iGTTYgj40W8nk@HatasipzbwBNvIKsCRJ0ZLHZwsJc9OJDl@2jBlbS9rCy30JIvZrOb92XZJJ89EOVysuzwOEXUnCD73JLN3t@T5SEHgIoNZbmLlv0CDqBl2ULL3u7BAabTRksO40OwM@7DLb3AsgnBbLSsr9MIXJZfh@Ag3C5PaINyuo8WTBN9DrjPHvjJ8sdBfrJZgPCUh@MQPgnKursry4fcsruLPntU8DzP6mdo2aVHll2wABHKcgcMHewMZLkJRiRFWTbAZIx1cMO751C3nY1NcMwRhCiS5RGF1o0zGcaJwh2T@eSTT/Su3zI7/Bm7/Avt7RB8rNFw/6D58cfNTqfpjnf3P36KPnt7n@jt8dBtdpoiWrMBjwNxwOesP559II@HjYbem@vzGfjYMz6NccPEvDX015An8XQwkX5jD3z2wGfetD6HBk8fgjbxud@H7329ST7BQz70HTWbchkJFZVL4CQ8tpkzG3hBuq8brlNG@6iywuKJeHpcK2TrZXJn/QRLXgL/Qv92gq4zx7EVCNqX49qokq1XRpXNnDiZl5BPR7m8JadX@jvaFogm@o6W20iNSnj9hdOOs7ii7SS0u2tvEo9BClnfKMmnOzuKXNPqOzmtWCpsvlgbynKyhO@d9c3SGxhuxWFMha9kbbO@A/LOJMrmZkrP5EqbmzgUK18BRnzoj5pD32w0EokLUz9LJjHH2MuDDEbFZWMqqlVuJ0bpUYVnjI0h/qiilbmyJZa9BqyFev6GeHUwB9lJIAZGO9kSLoYkZG2rKEMWMplEMomMCVkJfF8@D1Zxw0/EMGXkj8pKCr95XCsWkioe9Go47QbdvspeRkNONlhIz/F0JmlmCLZQ0ySAV5JOcKiJPQLJVlYTuAzXszGSRlydF@PzktrmliRVxfDqCb8OsiysH3@yp8KIS9hQc6B6gLKt46p7yPamfLhWu8DpBLo79RMTN0Ybgdse15mg7o9gZI0CcuARaIBShQ4e9eST8qXSwAWUr52cnZx8oVxFwR7DUJNnBE@WlUmHCGppQD2LVovplSqYdJQkKZeAguQFoaNRrVYalb7ZH/hjKHMQ7zPe0U4AHXq8MOGJN4p@iedAhUejkr2ahH887LP7PBAdFg2iNSr3Ab/Zso1qi020rrJRbCRVW6iE8X7l/uWwhNLoVdmsmK7ruHIMT9ju2JWh7elt84np4uHOw6NV1mYmHqM0ui9P9zHkHorVV0rVZfZUPhK6Um0mp50iVkRd4mshRi7pcAKu@V3B6CTxIll@DTZ3lSVa6v3kzka5lbjPGklwyb5sv2yzHCtslOmmnwRCAo5AmEOM6MlK9TMAzOGelUqQEUESZwATE1qFGrFa5KMnB9ZVuVOpYei3@NpWZLmuKLW3dalalqrAYMrjmF7xhk1@hXe2qeWyhfII3LTNjXKXNSvNF6OyWxnAoJyVe1DtYiaCn7jQcfc9IAngvHmbeP8r32DJbSVf4Y5lAva2B8JEQ21URpMaWq/UchuFdK6wgRMXhXX4aenceg43FKdz2a10TgOZAmQNiA@/TbBvwA/CgMiR03B6I9FLyIzJ6ewoq2ppzdTSiexLq/UymT7D@SUQCwlpybTv7NtAOeCABARkS1b46slUbq2XaDlM31aIhoHplamgerrLBla6i2CemnqPB08qbH0t0VtNYJjVk@Fgv1YvlUDO/Bp6JZTXO4XUZjb1JpksJ1ZYsuKZrwnLyB8JC4MVoGgxa8O8Yb@WXYFyQxtUrqC2/VVtM1eqDVdrigYFzL7tbMtVuQ7VdcUk@IsuKoPYVQa3gA9yQW0iak3cBihd90yoWm0rVxZBpIFgzAk5cSoHB4QS8fhmLh5Pxss4mbkC7oKxEwuOQ68Qv6vtyCDqySV5KycDT5/w82tZ4NN9BU2KXUk4vGUbW1LsUrq6vNqO7o/8jI3HOkje4rnLWCe1KrEMbQRSGzG2QiZFrdKs825lt/N0tyxC7@5JsRJt551stWSnQskDUzIrH7r9KLVdfcG/p7ixD5KVSFNXjdVp54BpkY7jz/HE2w6LQ7l0t1/L5dbrtdwm9OnAiIOguZxWXk1lWEyl/ZtQH96lxLHPd7NltlNVljmVZJn4Ed/VUMzTjCgU6l2MOADbuwwmOkp48URCL/H2Xqsn3z22epfFdYWPx4EBXV2xGN9anru2tRySDrYKf/Yyl4eqsp3AAUbgPrB86GbzeRkykHk58L7MFdcfHR7ZD9wDEyc2S1p8m7HB8daLzRfFF4@eHT07OpBipytvVxwYq91byWZLxVKRlcvv7E@/xgbx9Y041MFpJTaqbIjDIVq1qmjbObYD5MtKwPbbWkHJvq1yWqySRyEHPu9/5Qcbo@0i2HMgOZcAl/lUrlrV1nLJ2OD9V3@Ah4Mv9z/ffcjiqKzl7//0x7nNv//Tf0XbQeJXZY/mCTdjEBKNWmEzdnk5uLy8gof75WP1GM/TxmYSzHybjRarZmJiM422qSVjniKs2mY@5r0VUXJZPFoAvntH3EEu5KExxPafWvmcdm8b8a@F@Gfh37bpbcWkWPHRy7eMgcWotjodK0emTIaV3inb@M9wxvqdssJeVqq4MMa2wDOcNl2rVqtr5ByvpvD0ey4PnrWrcj3FcNr1xQBHb2v22unUzPSpDU6mt4Z/5E32Nc8Da2Az1155kEmWr2oMRn@ZzGny/a/8Zi5X@Ps//fW3jbeNL4A5b21tFbRc7GeQpSVnU4PhG03/4ClTNITDPrbglmLVkKUYXl3dZjx8MAjEYR/qZuCardAmnTuWUF/UAPTpIHMnKNganrBLk/RNx/GTZUkKRVSSrt2OkSYYbA0Vs0Mzki6lO@gFHRurAC@T7kxAgUMfVWIZDa83dAckKCYonlZPs7sQBVK4g0pUVuhkoGCIilZmmbXrUXmWuT4lEkVY3/Q81KIGDFu6A1EeAg3TNXFsoOPpUgxp2cCBVQxC@SSPVg3SrkPaPR6hQa4JKj0PkGY8dzySDdK3dAePypF4Dv01s7YhQJklpTuAAChDQgC26mybrSfZpZVKlSdq165w@yPq3NCDs2sSRkNoLTywGUQuYziLq1YZuqhujIkaNsyoYwCEw@DLahUYOGB0sqG8Q8dTbw0KYJGaggQVjd29O8lVpWK1koxKhPBR5xyqipvoyLqWAAALRl0ftUpymtmpFFb2nWmyA4ynKLtAdQoZJoHaeIgQrVeSBP@3JlqkyJmqIo8yFkDUF28VBqAMIiPaeR0aqDVPy20mWZh5A/JuUKZI/U44lDwdfaSSFiyDZ/FK@lksUGIM/OUkOuARdDt7eJFBDzVE9bKomYEzA3Eskd@GhXzq0A9ih7GgKFaPQrctF4YOtBgYKPJJrGtJjNYOXSgfxJVzGwx3H@aT@KFYGBrVveioOkWks0Iz3KRzzhs4NulaoVPruGmTNOB5Etcsw7M9tC900prGU6EtjZEccVV0SPmkKc3m6uA8HhcXHvn1BwI3aWZ2VFIqlNtiCa7cECcl7RBckiJRhmHAqCOOmz2zD1k6Nk2G2j68UibTAVFj2CT1Ho8soKvugQW9he1lxP18mQvrzMqcoGpUxWmD/CqOk8ZQOrFCXVtChwapyutZZyYfxyamzgN7LFdIg3yYBsxOfoDYEk7P4pnfLHineSj4bcJnkxuL6UjclcQ4ef27rq0kGlijb7nWKhfv4DvX7Qh@6XkridGnN/aCw/50@hTsashyoWXyE35xPOIXHkWVhFaCCp2YV3HefJAAuSo4o4pGEEnNcwihaBL2McA0jeDwLLZiKO0d6gCo7UHLQn04vlvCU@UV1BSXMKDpCQZvs4/Yek4ivYGkZ0GoRQAYWPWVaejgB1GxHJ7fgopR@RQE8BVonf0W@MVQPRQnP4wfUDeaSTfUhLzZigCHnQ6lVWG8WQSWfMSCrYNr@oOir4BnAXI4JycrCTkFYFNyUuagw/iz0Tm1S8RLSuw6pDRDCALVAAVFhfu6x3WPClU2FxcXKulTGrqWanqoMtvDu0Uzg44FAqmT8c3@QFx8ZOH9d@Juz4lJ4Yry8RbanRFd/rp1d8y/ktTG892vh5ZrJuJtL4594Dlqd@70SVUFKpHwiG4OLFIcbyRo3dkTZJarpy8DMishmSnF@BUCYQzBjNLjtJEGYOmmcZZuX7TKwoNfmw7AobLMwBFVHbqBpe8FJmvQDkM4Pu2WDuzN3pnh9BwUPWQ@0zpJmpcwCDkOrMI@sEYQyTYv2K7r6uME@ScxNNJpYkzSDRtD704@YITehF1yjWDWqDauT0UfhdGh7wpXW11UVCFdLgfKFbGh/4j7j8B/xP1Hk0SDZGujOpe80OkKi4PEjZqngpAIZhyEueJ65CY@BBlEZKZxEBhyPOV2BT@jQrEDfHMb1GMlIAygCVLfmEC9kbXTuu2ZF2v1VKYDNC0TIqDGAXStTji9aIVmxH7vvDdwvCknG9UyQecj8o1ORldQA6cVLGNYQUQYHF8Wau/p9FU@2cL7fVFggIDiFniiBLDrJ6xkOdSbS55AODV5gmOesZrITJ2ELOEl3EAq4qjniI0CqkcAoXtYJMgm@LCg5YhrEAQTeO7iXdRBWIWuNSAFwPF6HDA501Q4SylTJUVypShBNgHtKJVWZosS@ENV1Ga8IsW8EvUfzf7KB2e/De1ifu6JYHm/UJaiTcUcobpTUzQXwiqrViL1CjnIrOk904UOap@LoaJThmTWMsFogqeDReBqehORyjeSvH7obIpsy6WQFMaVChRxXOHNkreLAKUc4WE0T0QbB4Qg4nMGAjCyc6OZItooGm1UqXDGwUYLol1EMjmiTI54FB56tCCTdRENBkmhIlisnjrq/wOBSgZ4Gu8tUdetzDz9HBUas1eorQcGT0GaE55DVCBoCCVppDOjPjf1WiTTEaY1AwAJ8RqAFr95qSTNMjxNCW0hj@KoDHgUtwky4LwCCIxYcJlrZEuEREZDXZDr5RT1A9B25VRNkjXcFEZ/Wf6T04Fj8NOuO2anQ2rTjtn0zN8vxbGOmI000IiQoWU3kCHjgGWXFNSAWHLhsMQc4RncM8Gt3Zlmz2lm@jpusci4kbu8k8F4gJRQ3hs4vu47GxslPgiyiL6eieAscvcJHwNYHduBoUZU56PFdVTacVTFaTgd2/LMNN4ezkVwk7YDcGXsUlTuFUbHkyQx/ceHpQiaExCKro0G3hfXaCQ8s9dOlkKFqmhVkQ7jcQnHs2CKxAc@JIAeDRJO85Vp@MmbYaJCVBHtxDLOEkcD4RmHRHYZMCsD5Hnw7YKowjxnMhIkPYUoGjf9BF1u03X6TgfEO9RCirFnwB9OYGOG9MGA8pJmOg5RSxG1sdQcEkZaT4qon31wVPZZLqEnw/i5aQBTyEgzdxbHiFl3TnKNhcnxaEF6xx@e3@Nofo@X55dG1bN55kPtCvf8sKTXExMIEHCSjfWbs5EWSr@vZWcqK6EzClA8wq2z2KItTC3M6S4E3RXB1TbQRzq0eaSISGT880X4X16BQfT921afjtdnHo@B3/Rxp1yCLmPwgnXCBAQ/TCLvuZ5cSNoPbpkWhMW7SQ5QVgB5lRiXjVquoGEOYBjtyeESiQB8A83jPqVrdE@blyrcc06e3PM0O8strqIHjZbZ08dmKyFCpiNwgxI/hZEZ8avbFRwZHTE9hw/qEtBJJaNKshHpPFBpAcno6fOIivRrYXgQK6QemvmmHB4uxh/6X2PNOGVX4bPPIPDH4zHSpk@XHwzGgzHXDtojNcMBH@X9D69JPI57M0IAD2KLQ3qSbHIZ@3yaCIt0ix4hDKtOF5n0gAXdltMfXK/DD0PRzSWFyo1EqgS1PKXBfFGNW8tqPEIVAU3ypZ7bkeRNRHdrmouQGgc2YWF7H9aFXIOMWxsMIxGFyF2W1phjX@MJ6EbzbvaCXqUxh6GGMYnT@RaNq0m@SEo4BD6EL04gfQ5fBNgx/QYnqKBsOEclLrdh5NPXBxGpRbiANA5QIlgM7qmgbERCSYEZgl9ehWkaC9M0rqVpTKUZtoDpJCOBJGMqSVELWD3LqqBntv0F3Bm9cJAMn2VsGx7b0V2clriMW/GSlWbx83gJGHLcjJf2E8CU46146QEZvHjpmAxn8dJnYJi0rfjbeCloFhjABSsZ7qG7YOFoN@KlvUTySvLxKpEgXTVeCusUwuxwK2EEUIHlBqkRl8xsRxTTd03o2EioTDOkGC@N4ySacEnTLwv//M4AfrcNeOKc5RoFZimmTXUakR6DpwPdRqBLdk5LLonefP/ogLYGTS5lAP8UDOaicQg8iOGx@DQz4hlDX1qhgC9kEPlmaX6OmDZ9c8ctsiNSBwqlSp5On7CnkjzQSpB/DQLXk9MXQoj4QX1Ng@AVeLt8YuRF@byWnSA5yhGusSbnZAuR@jK@pFBY1zO3nfDaj9YQzV1PB8LbZYMgvJYIbISngwxHi22Y2MAZTBMJ@eKGPysah2bfeKNE6p2JRlxBtMwF3uQsSoaMIdr4k8uKE4mHWZtiQehZy9Z5Kwv7BeLF6DXhdRFJlTc@yEKE50ALN40zE8n2gTBSOM5u0tRXLOqGgrg8SeJc02wSIquoV2So@zz1cPC6j9pGPmz4GsQc4aRKAgFEYoapcP7qfID87nD5PRCoAyTMJDBPsJ7flV4Xr5f2sjM5702SvV6B6JlmD5JzhaMwhQnKYXQQkcyX0do1ER@3cHAhnycaQp@R9gO0hWOCG/A2O7bgsFBKcM@nHc9y4HiWW4yo6xJJ71wNhBYVUxJweMHDnE6KtjyvvODzqhh9aCJb731wBbvTFRytPIRHBXBnUM5bOR7jxLWtSdsmRb3ogixVKzHOyGn5M6zmiSOwe1qKDZdhweGo8fTB0eOHX4dOd3NzMyn66PEkf9hqcVI17Mc5ZNqWHPYHc4YtuTQqqsfFa7oNGW9qXjm15Wu8hDNrEAbwip6A/EQbTwpeFuHnM20X4vGwEYwKWGeTZqBPcSUUdXTssi2BVx8QYvqJNV0ACcRbwHeaRmtJnJMF6sDb/hoN6r4aDdyM1GiIXgyrJljhTv4stpIZei5desvVaF9IEp3HZg@O2PNPdk/YySf77ODZ3mfs60fP2PPdxyd4fvnJs/sPD/cY/PYfH@@zyYwCPni1CA4oAa8PTMPsN/Fy3Gx2gxHkPWcw5nwnsZfk7sd6n33iGCauR217ev9el1tU2/SrPNY@DEfHOIdp0f01fcv3@cV8BoAj4aZFh9dwfz@DsE0Y0/ZxzNt3WlbbgrASjn0HlukFJ6xYz4IaBH4bnJtMcyEJrzmhrUB0yR3dT4gX3EF4XKQBMLo3uVDR8ngEs6Uygbjw@WAMnuw/fXTMdh8/YHtHjx8cnhwePT5mB0dPwfrk64ePPwZ8Hh6fPD28/wy9KOCjoweHB4d7u@TAM5BVGZ5QpxsLl2VBxeCEFeMMl7jp8uvQFp11hmAgwbMLnY7xeSw@tJH7WHrPemO24mUJr0DiRwdpTYCFFxAy8zUuZQZrvrSfQH7m0SU@q1m2TalBY6lCeyuL5grdHipTx4WH/pjhZU5mmU6LJ8g8uSSKNuW0LJPJe7jnBOe@@aFyassBaEhoBWAjqGADSoXRzQTxeHqbQFYhNaPnoLI1nhrfFCgsGPVesHWkLBHGxN4XBIqb/g9tnA/SyqED0D045ESyvssDsPXQgQdgG9wBRdFD3AvC8iLE0D8aIntmBe7wqj84oPVfthk63NdpFFsUeeL1RlWqs/B2FDxi36O7JfgsD10apXuGZVEUj8Lj3Qy9XnBzY9MEkgeeKO7Zwr1qEFIGZtPGpQaxjc0eUsMGX6AG3Pejt32PJSpJlZ3gZh/TtvilHZ2ebvMtTZOtOER7rIhaRSpid7YV3oZBxygGDhEg3lAznY8w3gMhFZq3jQcx719LURd7HulGpWBL2U0ZuH8tAz8PGACkTI10DOqp6CwngnHagpQTngMUifO276LhgZxbQ8OcihDcq/nKevMmKZCcnhonBfsOKXdQRXgFaZqvWbYdF9o4sdU@HkpBLmh0nYFv8TpMTJdgcisahMaODVJ7WalOpUY3oc6kaDt2JNEmUPGCVJtAlLdJlSieL5KH7Cto6@G1bLSPDrOjN/Ei58naWRoXkS5MnH4BQZhfKYm9DV0QLORPacI73tE1n8VK9cH9U@XdyzReKcHZAr9ILdhEyK8F7WNa0DxonY82ILood4mWFtxL4g2bGFvsqRPcElt5AAzGgV0LxnX3GuXQj28fvu6Op01m3cnx7dsKj6UgZ@Iceeh1ExPulma1IMk0xakzsdcjwjshs8DrE4FLmmCG/PoeHizBWigDRmzkI3Sh7/R9IIKFBKVrDtvAWcSNX6K6Q/hJVqWtE4EgSU8iWh@ZF4n7lVQ1mZnsHGERdCYCFp0OIOOFYJP9J9RfXQP3YDk44N@3B1dcmjvePXwQtAdLoX1Q3pTUYli8W4rAuj3Yd0vA8s7t5wILZU8vBsw7yevQQkoPiTO9Ggt3xy5P8eW1uqO2B2Cw78UZlBBoJLWhTUvUgfrTBI@QjIKZCETHJw/2nz5lMh@fQFzgezhkaAk2iLBX@HUpfPesZROzU0OhKRwsh8JT4DK1dS14ljXmuchbwCqEDJIW@AiZxfT1pMT1RM9CIgTtpieGGGBuOneXAQ/yagLwFV7@CcwrNhHDwgJKc4sZ452P5UU3dQu8pblsHN2TTzumed@N14y54yig6OYfvYMnRebX33MuH5eCdLiAZb4eUoFbIEnjXbsqO4aEBxBQVadrcEm1BFWKm@a5gB0LcIc7vLLTEvYvTlBESFwI57JwhK0L4VhkjcvHq4GYQzsPsRvQcUun8OQ7lMEjYPHksh2t0OSk00tMd0EgZOIFWPeiVAHR61fl8NbcxKSfrIQCebStrVJuakEu6zg7K2CXFwf6CPc2F2bZw2xSwG2XJqX8wyTFe4mplAKczy1M4AmQC/n8@k2wZ0sRRFd@Udi8D5nln35/AOP7CUhv7NH0PlDu4eN04D8hgCWo41vlgwYzExFEnTl9ylTZqTOK5g/ywueFIDOoS9jo4nVf06km2Wgmb/Oh8x4pCp2CXCtDpAmHBeWt5hr2r5Ynhwz5xvRWPjw93tgwEO4RvPpZeLguolQl4oQnRqfdTNe1KRg/ltR38PgYnUZaemaODs3xDa28MOhJy2zRArTFISO@rTYdTDFQIjSrqOL1gDipV56d1VO0crSEB4cP99ka6aJrT01Byq6cjLCcFctelgFivTQdgb0GHcX7yCvBD/KQDkACmuhQXoJwk7wxb4QREJZrdHuD2PYpWKo2W@ltz9Bt1PCRlulu7bsQkSZf948OkvMm1LPlqfiQOW9gJyBWWlZUmaKCG87jIqRpELw20T3ST0l4fYHYILnkMmE9oxWzhS2JSmen/XS/tlVPrxkVmUGfq9t9b@hetM46Tve8zXps8Ko5MsZvXjOW32DrqEPyLleBqRUqeC47wVB9SJFtZYlgRQZ3SMnoqcyYSooTcT2ZTYbf5RWWJAONlUt4AmKGStlaP6BCPCnnV/q1Qr1iV7Llfs2ul/Gsnp@q@CktlUCHu9B5AmvhC/I1v45d6c@is62mfc7cYXMMo6Tw7Aejsx/Yv@MMl9izTfPltM1YuoOb1fAMiWqbF4nwqnSkTAnlH@kOHeLR8Ng3TRfjbEvLghwA9tMgrHojeo@T0p2sOhz4DvmIhBQkIfbWeivdCU4dZWnCAILUrHqQnW2CMwmTwHUf7jrmu6EVjUtjGh51TEZA1DAmcTv5VJbxCCBmVBy9qtUlTzV1o4uZwCsx31I0tr1NF2QCSXkqTdLhTg3dpYMP2ToacX0DPgNaTMAkSDD36PiGBMVHu4YG7kJTUD6dd6GN7hIJguiD27jZJR1HovjbgACO@DtcpFLFDKYQrEBO5Ef9aO4A1cpNj@txFQFPQfJKuYOFRdg8vcoEOO34JhxhsgJN4H7nAtHJcQWPKIGike1aMcLwSR6cUELL0MLmIS6pSsmrip/eJFoiEk0JogWBI6i4cyM2cCILRj@PTGg@Y7Zn9nqQaY6LOxN0oJGO44r0U2H6Xg3TrIeZ5/7KNX9lyl/l/jxTk1Aq9N@TQKVoIDl2OQl3xeRJsPS1tCqMZBMVatpQQeKYhC0vC@upvtOwJoGrYVVyqgw9tqc8lIjPizm1z31WpuKEBB7617i/oO@cqPkwl1Nh702nj19JVJBJe2PFVpIZKlVtq7fDO6fQB8lMBmwyxqNjfRPZ8UYpjkwKdgICGk7jU7OtViZQUlrAcajNyNXte7IqhImdxGw2@KHDaw1rThuJYInSTBHiRnS@ENIh75UICIKJhMaCllsNIo9F5HEELIZaCZLlhxavNXAo2mwTr@Axxrf4Chr7dOaCcLH5nnd4zke88Pww8jSCiOmuyPPRNM1N8NgHdxSFWtKLTNIez0KczyQeRyZ5wzRNfmS6jbPcKyGfiDKKgFNcw3voIzA9CaAF5LuoCtHzSvpZZk36WAcRetAzR2wXRxE6naaSps6jo6ZVD7UgkT4WbzgY9HBRkQS7CzrxLBR35PK4mjKBGFlGU6VD3LjDw6fRJM6PQySVHSHkC9z/MfHwhh28qBvXbVD5EbBWnFCxfFXatcd8vgLazHqOnwo32dDji6IwmO9EM8FrjrcexLQ30A1TlUAW80DKkXhR27x9i@lyPBaCerigSytJ0teGlnG29zEu125q2XUtgrJzsdqbVdc3JgelAEmBRy4L4mpe25CkyNKvwZd@FQSYZg@xo/8caNM8x@ugpV3oMSigB8KpZ7rnZkuVpKdmuMaLcJGUceERj007Q9fgczcgW@E10nja10vz1S6gMPxi/8xXgw1aCktLuCY1WUyGqj63WojA4EBJ28HFX1qPwFP9HB8YqW/6gJS1JJvOEi0ti7yQ7NLHeSbABqoliSw9hGiwHd8yoGZookrqASi@yjFJjF96H8kJpGf09P@3vWfbTiNJ8tl8RbqwRZXE3boalbqRhNr0ypZHIF9W0qACCkQ3AoZCFtitPWf3YX9gP2A/ZR/2U/ZDduOWWVUIWerLTvfMmT6nraIqL5GRkZERkRGRGOSbXQQARr@EGNAA6JOir8GQkDPxnwWDkoHpI3RPz0wOuN@Q1gosd3/cA@4bIphmhapFYIcJrr@q1lTt6KD@vnxcUfD89vjoXXW/sq92P9IRNp6DU@pX9eroELiLOSznQ/EjeGGVa1DTog@J8puPqvLh7XGlVlNHx6r6@u1hFVqD5o/Lb@rVSi2tqm/2Dk/26XAdWlBvjurqsPq6Wodi9aM09aqrJcJ66uhAva4c772Cn@Xd6mG1/pF6PKjW32BneGhfVm/Lx/Xq3slh@Vi9PTl@e1SrKBxYYr9a2zssV19X9rPQP/SpKu8qb@qq9qp8eDg30KP3byrHinwAIqPcrQCU5V1QVbEnGud@9biyV8cBhU97gDwA8DCtam8re1V8qHyowHDKxx/T0mit8qcTKAQf1X75dfk7GFzCfgArMC97J8eV1wg0YKJ2slurV@sn9Yr67uhon3Bdqxy/q@5VaiWVODyqEcJOapW0wuuoqGtoA7AF3@F596RWJbxV39Rhzzh5i@4MDkzye0AMQFmGqvuEYPRywNECko6OP2KriAeagLR6/6oC748Rp4StMmIBHSb26tFi0CEgsR4dpnpT@e6w@l3lzV4FPx9hM@@rtYoDE1atYYEq@lt8BNKBTk9o1DhPABc/ArEmNOWmaTpV9UCV999VEXIpDRRQqwq1ENr2XgnOYS3nEhFjSW@ItgHvKmpA6dx99cnHrI13LS@LbTEmwdHe0X4FdmRJH2WFH05g19mcy3wU/QY7jfkIP2MZZtp@87rb6A06Q4wVNdXYwHEVdNN424YD6rk6S3zlwhWxo1CFZLLReFdugKJbazSc9GNqxsB4qIZYub9WypExYgZ41LzRwPPyJeN9O4aonSU5xyQ/PDxfwJKM/SX2bPOufEflcm1fqmEQPjasTUQBn4pc4kkJsEaKZcR7JsIuyQJBv3tCDlTR1s1nWw00g6LjIxUaBvDP4KfwB28OkRfAndmslcuhEktg9D77uhvuhFIb0D@SWaDXoS6zge//2LXz0e5Q5892h8O27Ti6DpWdgB7YtZ0Hqjf97lz1zHx9ApZOlSVxfKD1bhJhzPGyoEzJvGTHNDIb/2lM6I@joeHcDWgUpa7IFi3GSXuJq6PDUVpJigqMnqBJRpnvdflD9T1qc/niamnu/SvzntcWugNi3lnY8E6p3jn9eXXOBWCBUU4NQElPMl3kcpE62p3EFL6BgpdYiDLr01596dO@DigBQfba60f7xN143JtGoQc@/N1x@fXuycEBsE6EdnVzbWO9lDBZsj6k@e9H7IeyoVKSsBHs4yCn0afIKtkDwYdWSiSFdkj@RMC5HBbEJOV60ugl5mswbhlxRyVkZDjcAC9dGaAHnuUjHixFiTSeJjS9LlyZQgB2bKgOjubKm5KI74GsRDQgvir9Gc3aFP/Bts3y10vcDEgISEiMctAC5YJ2QXzPOtCeoKTcUJ4dLJK1NB1z1jWDAzJ1kXssBs/SL6HtyCwG7KmI65WmnWoCEE/noVDabWLAK/st5QsRQy8l@4I3H4Te4PGj5KOj7HReMClPaoDGA1MT7dGh0VkGfSotn@@4MEVLS6anbYXWfEeAorUnZmOT4COyGgiUc/QZdNVcwyWTD2S@S3Jw/TblqC9MqZiEA9spCcXKb6DcRcORVko6D4j81tklFLdlkpUw1m5MHwld5KPJR6HRGUPTr8IHtf874mRB@9ugcULrIbYiOfsehUlqlXEF6ishpXejDxQipxghNqOvPobN3EYn5tIMTE5pphw@AyiQ2ZnpFx8pS2HHXoAAJHI0bETXr/E4u/RAdfrWcqQ6nocMWlcjW8leobeKO@1m1s/TJHal9RkK/nCUw7amSIeHUFV9y4pbk1Y9qExzqrx6HljcnKPzeOSWyQBiFjxR6SU7pc5TVl5WmeYDkjIpsuG0TeYjEEtv7z2dW1aRjJYx3i8nXBpR0PQOwnN3nJSzfKjY@zaeIJFzpNcpaR2mzUY1GTcfyTDXJD/Lvo/tPG@TMQQvk53c4AbR59Yps17YmrKfkx8IdhI6FYZpAZHdOllALW2rNwZ6skwihRroTwacfN5nq5YukeX8HQJhNBo@q157MwC5/7hhM4nllmvDNLomYmdslpD6eHFuazgcg@jo4bgBxnRv5mTVezE6@IPgeizpBmE/643FIqGFfugGxSbW3mmb4TznBFrQm2AwQjtL9EFDuvLRAZSzj0wz68oG4tU0uqONjr3pSkHZ2@GXbcAJZRElJG6rdfXTT1yKESoZPn3CYC8wygW5ZFI/eO5glt/NcPwj7v0oAg3aftskEo00SbZAnqTqgFIytiY89NEwIIsGTAVaQAwmCmxIM36osEdvCDmJ25IVJrPEVKM0kp/fjyFS7QwFHYWEK70D8a1nYDIRS0XJ5GlyexaKawTKIoXr9l5ljJJ7xo@nlXU2MCzlJQsR7nMtOuIT803z9BGfxMjvPg9w9cAbPMsWERQBRpkVz0/v8jmCDxPzve/543bUJgqSTNsbofmNVJ/hgGhRmw4lfV/LmwT@DDSAVq43zVEbDfv74eWgsTfse93esOeBnoYJz6fM8fBxRo84Yd3x8Cage3LoQztSqD0Lnzl9DKdTw9/mXLIUSbEVTPyRHXVHmIxn5UvOAkGWc/TxU2a/Ivoezec6M3VW18JKiXh4KbnbFZzSvXVfFBZV5pN7bEAY3M6cpwSHiE4o7igSW1q6U6D5tQIRGJsqozznHoe8GMRbgCI6holBrIG5434QHQRqZvdCfNqeptuUS3CMeZT8fR9vmglsep328GJV4CLfoEfAS1XYzEeq8inKFPMJ4sPsfnQXN35n6AGAXwF@4cUiallECMTiOjqZUsD6iiQFBVjI@69HPJo4MXCxXhd2oX6s0cZ0vtX459l92CAPHxCKJF3eHarEFWmD4oOXq9kNYDmNmYObSkqlHErLgSJIeWLn7ydY/yH3WFr8eIjLljNkTHvSsh0B@j5UtQBLeGXmnPdsFGROgfzwiikWHztrcwh0F3mURe5zsC0tuVCASY/3VzzWGo6BGVtz2BNXj1QwGY5Sj8TevbxjYYa1RbhuOc6Dfr5MbC5slsttQq07w8dZKTEPzxzRxDFGHmVAQ6i@0rMh83kkTt0Grje3MXsAD/fhLPSPMpuKme82r33cFD@hw67eaMySItgx2WjJvD9twMAb93MQaZPVqwZxjAayjMaMHyNNzaHJYOnxGCLqE9jn8NEGzGG/bcBddH7uReq8M5xOXao/xZJVIj4xzzrGZAJfGnXQ@QKzwLGEa5iUETin6Rkd5RUyTUwWjB@4QZSK/Uxoh2ILbjhZc3REyfw7dgO9hQrIieBpJ@rhYHL0G4RREn0x7ojHQ2OWKZyXuKWpaQm0Cir1tZZ0ODn8PG1MqZU7qIAlvgAVZkR3eNPl40f1a8cC5aAFrk2fxZE3n8bBOGoFoIF/op8aU5SBw66kZmxFxRdCg1gDrAXQUrp9n9VVlP56Y6Z49G6QZQQKBL@28c@K1MDs2@t5g22sMm3PsIgj6ObV5qjMDlcJCYp/I/plKbKoS4orNOAzxFDfLUALmJ6UoMdDAcqsE6W8GKAyR1DRLeCyhJeU3TT051zwHZEqBVbXIiXyi0psRdvILGwEBIvFZUJAQGZZXCRsBTa6hbBESmwsHk9YAgRiTfuMcZgKmZU4Ds3MMQLhkaA1HOW0oNJ5oWD6uLrmxD4a@qavW/nI1/z8V8CPgfA0U5j/upmPfY11WyzGq8ZqAj6caK@xj4AKJwqw4Qq/7j@KPImmLjc@oRElIyZliB/2AFWpG9Tbsj8EaptirrWModuLBn5r9avBN6LEkqt/PZG6kjT9pV8/WO2YqgGRzP6UdU6HstisD5LAauFOj6NCRVfn0TPpB7RKO@yod/WDg1hS1@ZM@xld@eO1fD6PNNyM5rDXLtRoSeoNc/HSuc51v58b3Xw/ftfMEevHi@n7wfClVqB9mBFYE0F2OO7yPQ4IAxTF0hkJU0VV/7rTiV6YgAeUOHcwa1xSch0o2n96xuflXZ3sP9Sk7K8XOEAc34Uyi@/GYzlTWtGnUFAbPYI/WfrwDNCDLzrohm0Oqqgx5MvamQm2Lcfd@YIbCN5DQpNFWYidL6F3svXK7/eHafV@OO63MQ/Ak9v5CgcH0Qp5LoIHjBS7ex1Qttm08j/1@pGoYSwSJXVsTu9L@lYInd4dU9wf@93KdGRbp3@2YFeBIa/gMFcwzXRaWV3LkZzvj2iW6RDAflTpK29ktwhP84Vhp5cFHD4BRC8K6YWqT6yIQyYxwdnDpRGpi8HNUioGGLpDooBOSU/TSyO5p7hBrnU2LXQQh3luQ2DCjCqPq4GBZL8fV/w06XQexxQpmz9P7F@dIdIRAK1AWX6AT0yG/U8ZWNYHc@lCWL7BOzfu8h2s0MAKicTzlvuXG7tcLqtno5UVVS7vwkMmo8q7ZbWPL3Z31T783sXfS25xba3EPHff@QIvd/XLW7ULbZCBc6V1Od6Hn/DNxagwdNbGKX6Wc5@lS88a7vZOKcidlncxaB@e/udf//1//u0/cmX58Z/4Y5d@nP7ZFMpms7lnrS/Plm5L@Pt0/zz1rHn6bHSe6paQypDdn4wDr@9FvEezrcQDEVLtfq95X9SU8Z7pBeSqie6SNvzjuqCB/fQTP51Nwsdx@Ig5UcPqXn906VF1RS3suKlyamkJnrbd1D@nyHYi7z3z/jO8Vw7yckqaQKjFe39UubZXrUbTjiPXJ@m942OOHLzJUvLlyMHVRVLf@Zc5VdmsOs@oCwMeunk0uGAcRFYzGZh/ESD16Mgnh86uRW3AQ2kyfbM5ng@mroIuyXfadM6Xn3miqTxvv@QzNGpjBRgeli@xr7rEveLwAVw89nIzp4X1tfNMMplMmAvRGi1ic9TbiPoyF2TpI3TKz8BhWCNYMjB2uqDORVxAg4iMZJKuy1pq8bVu9gBVa9KYWOFOpiLyPNqbaCAJw@bYws3JFFDGQoWPriBTwTVFYaBsMHvsGR4AQOF128S4FF@FHIz8Vq8zMy4PeCNF2DvslRgyt6w6dyLmlDVuWjKup52wQUAISgGUqwcbnW@QkTeEsj3idjxG/RvEjbtEdSHJv9UqTbBxCBoN@7NuHzqzyZUquAHuBJh3ZLL6Ax1Khz1wzaYPUo8vK5onLPTlRbibPpoiBi08IcP7ofqYk4sFPj7@pWyUsB5QwpH74ToYCmL3B@xANOzAI2z4GEXHR1hEhiu4pQpBoVKLyrG@X074wPLIcdSISyJW4Xd4@E7kQSZI0oflojtJE8KnMSNHauLbbaG0EV7th4q05AZ1ZCVZtFbM6RtIlVd4VonnlIAULJmlu8SANczURX9wYcbPp5sBXkeYtXSX3E2R/ROAY5ludLg8dcexABYbV@nmMTzhlNuwh0HQawKyYIgyTZQCkYMHxtDqWSrBnQm14HEgIhhfLY/MioqOT5OSPx1RfD7D@wRNuwNNBbGCeECKZ2I@nt1hjoOhsDz4NRgOMsRym/6k12IHSu79qebFIzwXp2NKAuz@jkB58HCcZoKphzOdXUiOi2mqw3YITxisgOv/0ojeHuFMzLzCoiVwBAAyxGFm5yxEUtiioQRqII4UgZH8vwWDT2KE2fe7vUmsTloyMLDbOY/iVqMeF/kFAhzF7hxmMVBCnzQblnAh@NauGch49TdgtJuOBD8voj09GNzV@OJJU5OHRPF0m3fpw/AjDU4UaljBgD5cvun4DNHminsdJZHDVJ7tOKmqcBa@2gM1LiAyv1imAB9qQLjFPE4yp4CN4hw2gJ3OLYOQC@djzUcIGIk7upMTj5pDL08XiwR3mLemFw0pEsFtwoT0fPn/7jc2lc0xxifD4oNSSAewR4cOJyaPxnyTC1fgja8FdUmOB6xxfI0Z6diRRXYUTGHT40Ua6dTAMdeVHrrMcIYkpRHlR4Gfp6noXM5V1eMNa5/Ha2dSHNL1RQd22RFJZ@RIvJd8fcKbOeymul2O2KKjN/p1q0PLJDLLOEzo2RGU0/bqdRA96BBDdyyZybldRBpah9dcXo9ZJAsQLmONU1t0RCPloj5BC5DEvgrl68mwOvntZXrKLS1nfeYlXbcKcoEHYrCICJ6Tkyd4RO9j57dSC5AP9IARsP@aF/jwnEiw5CEapvU66O4Op3Y@fWadWenC@pZjkZ5s5LBkKwDNKNnyOVsaXtkouidlZSS79iefWfi42Wu3/YHOxQpVpTfzqSHNnqI5/4thdwHfcGsRE/etCC8PMjCJ9EJwTc@jsde98ujxzbA@9mZV2ITo59GA57OG7R3DZoR3MtGXY16j5TaIGtYt6skhTTxqiOQV5YHk05qQaMCZ@CLiwgIE@HcQwH2a8QfxwUbQEB0/2y6M9Ez7JkzqBUsoATtRX/DByUWCL/y9whtpG/wOaNOO3Agsj/Rp7ppqkRHwg3YQjrzlGizq9/Gkxx/EziF06mAhPL42mmulVR8INK9Vrq8PZcj@0BcG@uBCFJtJ67Jxdd2f9GRkd4alx4WV5u8@JnVSX1d9z/3HZDKcx11kHNjuaQ9WaajLEKMKsSBKmG4loj9qdNP4yewYCg2iqnDaj@Iq0Uf@tvSVuWHpfkerGpiVI3Jgo5VTHGciom5A7VIi3GeVGfXTmPKBcABSEIzlEV08Taz5NjrHOMOYN4SYiZncv4bO/res5PIbOm0IsaT1UnHPZB4W6voUVZBWeTnEjmi1QCl88/jwyhfNVtSJiPIauTWOk2n@7grrA5pbTPqLoEp7bUdll6exhRYTDrW/ZgSdRoihnTk6CzTWqDASlSSI5YwkMQLjWVq65aj0hWyDlRIoyTDPC9laYjIjXcDeoIk7m2faiBF3PjlaejMSEBUFmmprpiq7W7ixib8vWvXCHUzDGpcpoyK7CjfQUGZdoIQbMngQUf5dRBV@GaIYrkV44i@/GZriCIhj6TaRWES@hnWIa1Z0rZsIojt8iRD31AjCc20sEHSbfUwaGAI23xxMoJbst7QwvKzKXWCLcVmYHcO98B1rPaxABnMh48YQx2EI12NMqpsE6SoB/2OCY@BSV2jQiVlAQGTNJUwhig9DbBC@jTVCUhaoXNJJiM9QLsnXBBU2Cg518oieMAL3V4j3zAbxKKZzJ/gNNxQSOZZVQwIIH979aK@7xywdG99CkzRw5NAozex5eTTCoIKHrNS5pKSysBU0rxz1Cw3UZCsp8h6Edp5cMvEEQGBJA3PqQWdUe0UMvIEPwzAZOdmcG7phsX6oDd1/JPu3xrH2VRAKMAJCXksHKJ/RFdA8wSIhUCArLdDU8yAFqDaxMwt7CUU1EhcJtTFK1jt4QbbqhQYhMyu0SwcqvEF1PIlYFRdaTbWFSCUXVlM2phhFawYdHfktNIQbK1XgROzBYnbIQdtyIzeAxYGSpskYu4oOZ2lJCWxksp6TMRYq@jFEMRwxZJwNJN5ijnSBCeFLQrxsKbBMjNQ3Wmh/4AJSIlydS4sFEWSvoRwSWmhyId6vBwbzi7FDVb@GHwqGGM7FGxFOiKOa3C8hNImfi9B5fD5ApGTQ@9uh0p81E48lVbm3@z5a5L14o8B7cXTvmQU5tDbg7oN/ey2O86XA0nD/UcvR4OsnvP@SmQL@YQKleIWJSSIA3D6YOHLX@JNQr8sGkwZfm27YL@px4nLXbsN2DMyWAprSoCdOyAdJRfCsHWwpwcDP2jC1ks7dCysEFRNBmdfMpHaolylSzCLqr85KQJjqSBj3E2iO3IsokhOProYtzgsAGxR@71BWANJrC6wWoULEFU/xp8RUPulwmsKOrGQegVpuSLcyBoGHBsEy1u7YmzxKxAqP5NhhXw0wSRRIWfN0GGQTqvrzRbLHyGXLj5bLkstk014OxbPl5Ahkixe/sI2/rpwWGmihHctAbuFCJQM@qRyAYpigPnoYh8Z84VrRI7dfLvb9Q3z5o24My3948WXZoL8VF2KWQyGmtVCICQtIrRYa3qieKU/sAZbtgDTkZRF7uL9hvD9YN7q/4cL@@CZ2FZaTykPqFl8v6HZyM5QahlClQ7I/LuwIeS2v6QtL1vaFsu8uaJ7vcBt@8Y9t@O97G84ZXGC20Qd2msjU/2Pu/x7mHvNX9jfzm/nGb3bua95ZUcKy5s5blbKeqsLONxtn0/382XRr9egvyUlyp5h7P4a/k@RfkuubSX6EB/j1Qv/6lNxJbmOx9dvkLOe6LjxKK@UDaGXne9Mmlpptwz87a7rd9VlyJ@NS9Z@SO@vwUCgWAZKzaWXrbLqZx/@t0h9J/Iierhjh475WR5TTRjYEPgsUF3lSy4dB2OReZHeoIglodTxuIMWdHxrNEMDoPDMtbuZFVgEC4uQPn3y5f0unzRD5kfLHTCijCUdc6LQP4qvHlWAFmC4c@ENd0G4voleYcELnmkApIQRaXTzPruPR9YXkoDAAmHwTJGayKzeoFzZ1jOnN8O9O/hvL5KN4acWSYMTPNmVX3JRd8X@TajSbXA4HxQVZ7ZNqD6Zr4qsfAoYlGPRGI3/CEn/XH/hjSmUCw0FBB6/Za@GlhP3ej@z@91I3rlrUUOOHoMGxOdxQdjRT1rNvYWX1rkgr@gyrUj/j@dj6qv4FjBsvbMM4GR1d0@1NLq@bdCFBfTyrTo4oE0UOk5pPOCtFDmS5Zu7KQ8cBSuMfAIlBCWAH4@tBji52A4ENY2Uw9/6V9yOAhpfJwtDaDSiGxv4fbbq5NfBHFOIy7XQsuibJ77dr/sgbe5yxDr3mr72uX8VMPDAZwaWFylNSvaHgmkk0NbFRlgjjIIfLfVgZzh5GvD9I6fBPQq1SGG5M1/VYGKcuTIh4t5WlqAmoZXFoAV0R3hkOJ2F5jho3FehnvAblY4NJ4tAQPBwMRwTcHMe/ooFYUUpeEBzhT@k0fEEdETRj1cNrNHBU/uD6imjHXGt7Wnh5Ljnr3ELkenHyeN18KVfKWxYiFKdJjM2FTfxyzb6XdC6ZkNQBZhwgWDMkUJAn5JpOC69AUwiCYfMHSrSEXAkWJNJfVn@TZU9u9PCIxu6B3/WIV9w0MRkPvG33AiqANXPdzyC7M4rSMVJtXneDLK8FCqzoBcG1v7axuUoA0Y6vi7aHrVjRYg5aHnvjWY6Au5xc9c0otiaXqu9/8vvivUJgUzpfXpREZ3ijmXfdJ7eWdYdIB1AZGylgwd5K87v9ysFhuV7ZT4OYsobFAwpLMmXtCHL58wp97/QxUwOTEVbh5Zttrq8ykdtBOvUtWuQY9G@jaF@JAqwbCIIs7gG9kZ1yqZr4WXDDaoRq@6CbNsfhlGpIZ43G5YagXNNVE5ZGrl75ySSGdAXYVxJJMJbYAOrgwHTk9rgPjOdOoXt5BWBAuFtjAhTZR/6JlGttP81kzJp6SU8ZYKyZzA4bWay9fg8Uz9Tx9SDGbVO0djyVAiaHx//M2p6miC9krZK6dFGPL7XcfMnE7X2yr50v5krqDkJhM@Lqw92Znj/7WiLTLECIQ17OOmTyv/8r5ZRuwyQ6fXvi4NUL6rOrM0dnmalX@K5aOxW0YLImUO1zduJPJ3uc6dOdlEyF5rA9y1JyrfYeaNVt@3O0j5HtfIG9emWl5bovnC/Q5XiEGUBHwAz9OrTolPBdJ/bOhIjlzs4GeAH1MobufXh9@AqmHP3E/GBy@ufz5We5dCrlOCUcgudSfN/@0eu3aOUfO1my9h@Mh1eCl7FnOsnCbF8Fp/lzgj5t4dByuAqBc3b9iYw@2J3Vve4bkJbslAcoQLckCoyDSeltexJfVkLfJJS58HKWKI5cKz65lvOl61Kpy7HfKbGt4jZwP9ldpzSBP5fRLtagC7dYpNYnUMlFr6Y5rPcGsFu/qr8@dFPbnsJW3QWrIrXSNMQBhEIEY@OrMl5HFSMd4CpEVROO1iOCgf9WUtZOfCzbOW8nVbq9vReeQ86nC8JPKiTgtn2dFoobu3entDQOqWA28l18wVvbd5W6lYa6mIIFXw5we5sR0@IgVlf3weSGnIK2wFkNy7ju6tISvcMq14HrFvN5BzOi3EJrAd4fD83ywhqXbsee27YNIr1Rb8FtScVsMceBLEGusF7Mr218MxzDFuHihfRLAbAQF7WWT73JbAlkQ9/VNy8tgZwMu6n7dHV586i3@6cPW7X1fbvV/L5gpa0fAnLbH4@iAIy9myyLRcBjx5Jrl4DAyMWWlxt5Pw5zq@18CyTPwkbb31jzN/MvNltr/out5tbWVquzutlsb214G2utZg6TvVOV7FVvAFKSxeSP3XYe1@19gtlmMb/V6RQK6xvtta3OVjH/4sVqc3OtnV9d7WwWvBcv1tvFzeZW8@tSWwhPAhis5ru4d8xz4Of3C3eJO7xdajv/Bw)

I got interpreter from [this site](http://poiuyqwert.com/zetaplex/), but it is down now, so I uploaded it [here](https://github.com/stasoid/Zetaplex).

Zetaplex is a 2D language with graphical output, like Gammaplex.

Most instructions in Zetaplex consist of two bytes, there are also single byte commands like `<>^v\/`.
Single byte flow control instructions may appear inside two byte instructions, for example `MI` is equivalent to `M>I` when IP goes right.
Unknown instructions are two bytes long.

Zetaplex takes the path of Haystack. Zetaplex traverses Haystack/Reng/Reticular/PingPong code without any trouble because most of it consists of unknown
two byte instructions and numbers. Then it is deflected to the line above, where the main code is situated:

```
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
```

Accidentally Zetaplex leaves Haystack line between instructions, ie. we are not having a situation where the first byte of some instruction is on Haystack line and
the second byte is on Zetaplex line. So `` `p `` is the first two byte instruction executed on Zetaplex line (it is
unknown and does nothing). After that:

```
sZ  stack zero
283 push 283.0
MI  math integer  283.0 -> 283
On  output number
Dr  display refresh
Fe  flow end
```

Without `sZ` the number would not be printed at (0,0) because there is some garbage on the stack. Also need `MI` to print `283` instead of `283.0`.

Using `/` instead of `>` because of Retina 0. Agena comments don't nest, yet another `#/` is not a problem.

The `;;` on Haystack line: one `;` is Reticular exit command, another one is needed to keep PingPong retval zero (alternatively, `@!0000:8:8` could be used instead of `@!00:8:8`).

*Note:* LMBM marble from Zetaplex code and the first marble from RunR code are currently not destroyed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

## 285. [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98) ([cfunge](https://github.com/VorpalBlade/cfunge)), 13300 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo  anet   /112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                      @,,"76"<>␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 ata""[ x];#mint}=>+;dnu91&&1-2Prers 6 4>80::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*sExps94 Cr u Uithw;harc""2:2FACbody+/='d  Float#  +- $;#8;在e*n*    
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}} #@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;@,,,"285_";# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51 @!00:8:8 ;;~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 :  Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//   >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2AAJVQIEECAIE2Gw2eS/v7W72NNm371wQjS4UCkA1gSp0VYEEms2OmfHurMbSeuXxWDGakXVH45VXWjnCWodtjdaSHSG9OhR@0g9ofWxsKDY0/2D2nJNZhQIIgOwZTcQ@bJGoyo@TJ79Onjz5dbKpe92f/SyGD3vi9MadnuMz3/R81nKtc9NV2f0xu6dbXj63LkkItet2hn3T9r2SFGMaY7Z5wQ5tw2qBG/OdM9O23pgu@OUYG7hOx9X7zO/qPlgsCMUemL23/bc@M5x@X7dbHkCuM/ZEB8/20DhjetPzXd3wLccGrw3Gntk9vd9s6QwgTHfgmj6hzzNAYZxRmGmfAmOPHNczMXrD9DwHHTcZ2zb7A39cBUsRIHTXch7uPv54JvAWYx/rkLJBzxzNpEXLsueW6bZmQmga@/zk4GDWNcc@UxybHVxPn7bOnrme3tNn8W@w3aHvHPqz7nm22zFtneXULTU361lg9139WpBN5pp6q231TNWyDaawrtkbmC5DF9Z2XKgy3@wVs8VsY3cSUjUwbHHiOYO2EjxMdzseeDrnJhhNqImBZbZY23X6TLe9C4hJ28pO4BHt1jQ5GJBAIDT2yoPQLZN5tjUYmD73hOyaLnlDzKxn2WcSp74nrtMaGpbdATgTynUw9ClPnmRAsCobCBpW0cBiVAocDJJw7PTNaF14QLyQam9gGlbbMnjhmCPftD3Ir6cyC@ruwur1WMvsQYAJdiPNPIcNvYhTs6d3VUOVsHAxFtY/6zGLGYMB416QDUjSQbbIzL7zymJvwL/X9dho0Gee1Qdv33DabdNkb8xBF4KzfosZY0NqORKDxxjM5C60rZoAY5uQw70nX4ey87FI7TYkr8WaEThIC6Wbcq3bDhShy2y9zynCGIypBABNGKLtOCq6txzTs@M@u3DcM9Y0DR2zjpF5ZqetD3sQo9XGKgFasDzWd@ALFWkzSBYE9rE8EDdGJs3NCEYTVLE5gMaJVewgyUB9BzV94epAI64n6tK3@kAhlh/3mKl7FnItCOKZdouoYxDyMwdyG614dm5B44OiGLqE2zNdIn/CyzAXgFIP6TVx4Vo@UAXmYpc9MXWXnbimmeS0anqGPkBKjUYJkTkYg48ZUYk4t7fj@0cHcSBSHkLVB0CU7vrJ1z6VdKZW2GqjDL@KLJel/ccP2OXqKZo53wRCHrgJPckq75iXOT014TfSmpmOeyUBVglKpccyzsDP6MoAEqj4kMCMjkY0Kec5ddCLRMy2Z@og0nQ4VAtqAxgB@zxNOTOGroscflKo@hlkuufYHShPyKw7tHmVF7JQBUB/LS/NzHMTaYDXkXNBJXzSBQqBfwCNcBfe6VCBQrcDzVGUaBCv5/SGBAchPR/bJJQKBEWMh232OWvrVg@DgD@i4ql2TQ@IE8MM7RbWfN@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@ftICsKZ11of27o6ZYSITAW5i8h4CIxlSg/JAmGVOm2WVXD4/3WiutRnfzewqXwLXfZNZ2jQw89HWgZyDtUF27ul2Z6h3oEk4NgTRDcMc@ILzQE48H3jLbAdCjoroDVWvK63em42beoVA5pnEQe2Hak/0bTqyCyGLKyBooTzHBXzWgkZpUDOYjh0Azmcil18iyFQCXsoLkhB06UBkvJVD4wYCvuha0EovKHU2Z3S8V5mNHpyisQOrVtph1JgYrXo3J6mZ0AmTsRCFgjV6HQ/0loiqOuVAlR91WI5Z9/pzEDthEoGzR1zVjK4C7d2As@/YzhykUJAhWgSZ9uH1AKLVMUq60BMFchQ11lD8DasI6gy4BrR8oL@u7w@8EjB@y@8OmypQSubEHR/6RzYSS8Z3x5bvcHOz5zQzfd2D9pkJYsgYw6Y1mskQuYV1@MqTzkGianuswpD1AtUl4m0P@Ca57yFwxEsmKYdQ8LcMgASkQkEl2h6x4gNgKsdj20jIU0Qpp5mMbVdOggEDhkXzKUpj08l8BU6zqUSwaGLUDEJlPNcggxIRMhE9glOypDtTWbtlGqU7sgyvtt7zTPjaw14PrUObc7kE7/yT7FK6cwdYW4Kis/qDnmVYfoP7srt3hZDAVmDghnJQG4WgJIS5I0bIKjAUgBG9D4dWfeeYpNdEEjJy52oqYtN1HZfH63dd6NTJAcGkaKE@ts6GrZlStdENi1PGMQQKyIYPEi@Mr7jcM0ME0yU12/eyOJYUkgqG50yzwmSBj6K6RjrkijUmi2BCSKyIpEWqMIEpSnO8ADy3tHho4RbN/J7Tx66NPSfxEccDMFC3bJywkLhYQVKFPleqCAUKkv7jcfWVY9mJy/jKykq8FK@CuLCysgOmbTTtoCkFph0yKWRCOBVNFCJNJvStUQh0q8evagHmUbKOvGCEQ5w31iCh10ql9Xpar2nim8NvEogMukuAVvADeOLJSgWNyaRcvYCMqs32dO73sMs/NlxrIArhU/1c53ZRCutUDEC1jot1UcYyX14m/Yprqh4MbYxuwo2f1rKn9dPL01bq9CqextDJsl5pQqYgvkRf7bjOcJDIJmsbJUWrJ5O1dRDFmpV4Nr6WSBQVGJTCuCr5UTGZ0nlpJ@ImiAKJ09M4FKoon5rRdQnfKJ1LJsOignSgtAcjh0RcvSxC/M1kPZmKQ9hkPA0D0Uo8DiVjYCF4lGmk/KkCOnr6GS@YvVRKIgKFMTb@rskS4IZD@OngT4Zv3iDj5jiaIYX1hjofDw4EQObQDmBV9JwZggdezTbDTmQqjo@dNh/j7eFr/@GBZI6otj4@Oth/WqFourp3BgKV0kHYjOeDOKG7LRXaUW/YMqV5MMAzwWRMUoKzIRh5xzCY4jACUwyeiEhfabAF2IDR4pSA6jCl15/OgteF9O5N5YGQkDuFXCa8GUGSOPjcNIVRHkB3tXf8cGrSr38GwhQzvB5OfiguzwBYM2vcsUWfGLBD3XOsVokd0ojTBukaaAuE61Y4s2E7toIdQTA4daIR8ekdgCA3FDVRjLKmYBBx2xrBAD@Gs0Mo@@EADEgIGBgUmA1DbVN9TsxNZsAkcf4NRmLzhkJPuBSpGt6kdcJoB4yDnm4AC59GdyqzU0AIHCiTme@TLF9DDCOjqYERzUrclEeQIw3dxvJrWTTqHlpeF4sXBlLYBbptKFUccuNYkkrtkBkg4negpM2RJfoiaOHHGOQT3UskcSy6ywdZSGU4QMBEBXORJL07hjF0TRgooC@f/GH79rnlOjYWsroPqIEVlbEOZpDPK14go93dw9yDxeU7DzmU2DVnLVK2UayzhWt40Lpsp@d0HLYGAEiaqsoJ@9DGOVvotH19AC3KekMFtNtx7PEMDZpmOAtcWEeS5zNTCJkhePUV9AJsfqYnAAvyfHz45T701lo@m4X0B7YsPWEmI1hm84iOBpsAiHWNHtIN1uSX5qA7dqfIyXPELJBPU6HUMPm8nA7yM6RKtPA3FDTayLkLtPPAqxWY5uV9nwZEOBU5GC/I/ZTwwZsN5DA244yuQVFMIb1W4ZP6RcZ1mpniW0HVnSvtvuPrmc9VYNH4knB4oFhM9jLxlXhGUfAtkxfLVVmmZZ5nkEtNMI/2caZmDu6RaRoZ9MXOjQWGucUTeC4omlN4bHpBNvk3KIMw5Gz@O6kUMnZKXRg3TzR08ifdoSmZRtdh8imMr6I5k6GD6FotU4GSB@kXB2VhMLHGJfnOEMa0LbNn9S3/kFYhejYO3FRi3ipyLeG7B/xmguCJZcJohM@2TDoZXCmY9FF2h8M/BU5OWD2fqbxIXbOVWZtge@Q4bhentjSaUMmFRd8XHhnHG7RUfwQIeKh96t@9oJ9/fPRgv/Fk9@STSmbouZme1QQe0TIbfRjJ96A5LHgwbTjfuQ@0Y9lO34IcBSjfnPWeOo7PhQdcCrndE8OAAY6HDxoPD@8/3X36dZE46tGt/rCnYxpLqzMAIY5jglmKxnCaDsgW9nAhJhAuju4fPQywfPrs4eFu48H@k6OTCJpXw56la6PM4KyzKEOfIgjT1Cwv@qNea3qNisboU1MogtnggLPMYGDOFAXeCrrxSHFIqqIHisjYPSoKzmnrOGvvspyW3dpqNfVi0Sy0jI2NzbbebrU2clox3y7mc/ksvDYLWyZ7S@CKYo5o2gpMfEoIZ88wDkg8fTR1I5BwYBxugMQynpuu0HdJ4ox83tzc2NK3jK2tLT232VrXc8VN0yxstjeyWbOgZdvNolZcX5q4SDJQtJrY@jT9Ba0OZ0rIE5hfAj5TzYEnHmS9C9bK5XIFI9/eWs@18tmNVnMrmy@2mtqm3twys@2NdS2ntYycVgrCAo8FxpDpQoWhVGmDaBp4KRp4JqWgM41WMa2bBgvrguGsriOLGQQL4zhwEB4b6DEUy@KAM3DPo3uwKI7zU8K9gO59XBKfSLJkDR0FYJEAcWVcdZuB4xY6hmviU6vFwCoF/5znvziQwHypZa8Q@QWuqkfyd6lp5H7ut9tTzjlyPlOwK@tNnNfJma@pT69mi8xe85oLHOLbIHx8LX4uvmtec4FDfHmOD9fw56Ob8ZkHGiIrEDJc85@La8ZjDmCIaZMwRfcJTPyK5Ldok4CIa673wkAh7i3Czdf/G6@8BoraDbH8j9TMG8gJSGIPHZCfH1q4aNGeajFSOAI/leRgGmF6Fg19uOySOZ8Z2SnncjQcb/uWfebQODk0NbKqlsf2HIbun/Wuh2zDyIJeU6BhGgI5ZkHqvH6zTa85ANjHzs5CkgdN8YqeHnpWPfOUPjjZOy8F09PWU9E3zfYQBj2ZpmWj@QYwZatIkO1m01oECiWBuyeC7xywEns6hIFnTt1QtWCUi8tEwKL5nPPJ4REBNnUas02vdbCpwveHrg@hxPe/fqMFlXC9irr6mIZ@oaFhmxdYXUp7YY2JoGih1/zanXTyVDBkugmloeN6sd4LDfNRU@0rSld3@zjCEtUNBIovoIQltMZTzqdegu/8SEqMCnl6TYXZVp8Z1/bS@I7DPBg2T@pmZiWIx0vDa1yEpRLhg2DLpEAu1juvEXPEh4MRUQf6nDkpnE1fsGDDJlse/O7QH/I37nK4qUatAf6WtVYBmc3rTc0E4VhvWuaS@nf1s2HLUUDGoyxjwgpzYCe5p2k6pd3Tz7ixgcb52ecZdK1OByQJ8V0EdtGFUQ0NRzMX9LmJRDx76A2UJlSWD22IbNQq@kticHv8vQjEEnsBQ8PiUrN69LpFpYfEReQCwhwVNG7PUiKFZs0Uc09vjnGQ3v1wKsMISbQB9lMxUqnsOnZ44ZJ3dEvV4vDYS1L4ra35ofnGMF4k8wZWGb4hTOFTx5RnsUXshoqFPszq6z0l14oYFzL3YNJ4YpoDSjM2itHTPSAtX1SHeQ7VR69l5I6dlAEDLndiWkLsk@QEOx8WLaILDiZateH0LA@bdm8RM51dd5zEiVvz6BWZjLbmFWyLpCWvq4Sm@XzBMXxcwV5AaLfgcnzxGJfnI5SjOosKzXAu8LdQyug65yZ/z@/z3sxN1S04ltIjkrCMuZ1L63ovAk68i6d5Vg@EfyAmmm3VaKjLd2sE2xPyhcHr67WAe6HoNb/wz@Zmxjd6c92nG04wIxIdz92yMXhWz/HYMb2XlSVkzPP4e34ziBa7pdsKLR9FzfODiUQNmComZRcQg97rOL1CsZPR4bWQYoZuGzsS8b0tywxZnqbdzPIC@cqxNfFd2FecZdyzm@qOVjJc3OAQMS7ptufxPbGGuTiDQKK4a2l@5g6yRQqpZvjwelEFuEb3Qh8H35@jO1pUukF3NBiTvA7iIwbYKoLBd7kM//PEtrE8ttbteNo1tJs3ZSJSuWc9E3o/el@rUpbLah8YQstmb8/h2r2hOTTnMrij5isTN/gvGcXcPlFZkY1VMTmKE0g4NRpCvRHjz1ulGjt@tC1lMMBsoZHfKB7N5XcDEOwHOEJ/AoYnaLgesGMPB1OVOzUKtJ8uL7nuIGjZTmsqkejzoRypeLMQNiX9eyb9lg7O@GASl8IqG9lsVghFkenuKcuyQdt6GPaVxd9TEZPLJOYJLPacbsQ4P47JzCtUvXXmKTgHejvulFs0o0DAW1sZ27JNf4zvWzLapuP0PqT2gN@2LJT3QIrFJaKbavGaLCU2zbHJtImHky7N9qIJE94XidEsFByO2ZcRQnSS9lY1rKBwAw20M2NdPoUUmfK9KRbo4Wleim@y6C0WVMVkjKYW1c2ljZGLv07T7On8MypsLMO3pa4vxRdKK0KuplUwXDnja2WTtdfYDMsajKGwrBYMirpm3yTrktGE3no19ILPQqCRg7853iqtTC4KN7CAR9j4nlqXi0hRvmPDMM7X3Y6J46Aerp8L10V8OZh/n1u4h329Y/IzZcsY52RqBHdY89HjxDh/kqTE96cZEIxvEllOCtCYzsyxF3znInw0NqA@h/2bZ/lm2r1BW5puauhqZu6yww1iot11unbX7PI9Q6FtUfMAivT5acBlmYD0d7oGI/4U3c8ULdme0@vdpmSRP3Ju6TjtuWnaxzNqLQj6QXjHehM8xOfG2UPo5qmAqL9f1G665hB6K8/xnYGpkG0RaA8nl/h7ERcNloF@3lmrpTMKUCLB9@fFb9wUsKM7/mBAn8agN/ToRUEVOlq4ZMjGp84pSqJL5rgd9Y3Tb6rCUT3g30dQ4QuYTRPPueAWJk7ZZsdpGl3rpkQ3Td23rbNMMMfErUuHvYNIOVlMeYDOas@C4nXHKtJLJep/jJ/DRZUupqt4xxYa5lNBie0NXXeMlB7MRdOUAW3JmpxZnnCV6f0Z4WQxX@5Aw6JUiZXHOd4kQ@DOvWCH2pI1F7FQuZAsSWpHCV0xsyDmaAvnraa2j0ba1Po6fy2SpmbyT4mKrA9/yMSr2FZBU5BWZH4Y3Kdoamqxe24XZ3eHHe86k@TLAi0QzPA1t/Z3O3gK/BaVzysa@jLdFp9FdZDrZXC/PHwbUJtDc@kST37pGg/BaT1Fdyz4NOAD9TpcOGHXswYefzOlnZsrelxftr4ONZ4/9hZ11jLbfBUGTTfJjH3HxVNbIJwohmt6Bk7iI2/nkhjnY7bTAR6v9NgEOICdm4XrK@VzSSLsO5UvHpsdHbd0PrRwd2dvDqUA1tkF85uQfm2oe9bXho5vzsU3u2h@E7pHescyPpkq@QBZUKJi3x//TDUFdLpe@Bddy6MDM4FhycQVEhknW6SzBowc5g35ZhYKwuPly@dmIiKX2G/OlEMW7EsPDbhUgf763LjmrQE4Axp8jsm0bPrf8ml6V3znUtX8jQfLor8Y9gdDT3zmx057g6KT4/0zcvcuLGCVymvg0Kyr9/z5E@iR6V2Q3kRnOjEukue/tHpOh31ZzDIQ9kB4Q/F@DsHdh279ie5Di7DnEDDFvYCXzy7R4syJwrmk9xpowlxnimVb/vJZIt/XYbQVfDEzvAPCY5@Zh/hW730oBuVkfok8XCrJggwwNnqoVoDvu/NY0zWhC@XKDMItcss7MwNo8ZgO/6Mx1D8QpX4RmbkXrFaIfsc2L6Ljv6WLTiXsbB176Ct4vmDpcvqkkyks7WRKbFQsRGiFJb62/@hZMkoytAf3JhHXhDHm0OuNJ6aF2yFmKNGyQcpbzJynoYOBygOTtEQ8pd2iN4TZHeD5NeoDHjjzBlNPxq7p33o0Bj3KsP/ANHAR9Ma4HzuPQL6Dvm0AXLj/1OTH06aYy/yAGOyhY@g9KJ/WjdEcE9o5ncdk3K4PzCbUb29imi@wzUP8QPf1BQIWTUfS4DI03UgrVq9puq9onjFiXjRenk7QJ@aIBi6LCYY3SMU3DC6V44zfVHOZXTHyBo5j8zdx5Sx8tEfLuQ/0F/S6/eK/ipuop7rDueO/6dweheoH@NHJRdl1zabT42/MwoKe0Lb4PgfdtUwv89CyhyNyK2wwBcS5@SMkvps4q26SChhoSMESa7jNGHfNCd45MwwDOflc92gHwvzBz9SW5tvvd@rqruHgqpwwfOCaXORs2g1sPdyzzXdKNKFiRsDUdGMoTjndlNRev9mn18LBS6S2n5pNPPvXpLOpvj6aJ1lOn2ETjjOnyAK2ho2/wBJPYHiUvHnGbHZsN13i1oBexNQv5hJKEN1jyzTe6MlbjasiLYqmrDM6DYHnNqrpbXogA/VMxe/ips@Mv2wuPTgfPGdBZtg3cQ18eiVoISk5XpfowJm/6h@yWtcUO8dx1yI0@sCM/FbZXUioiB7@j@5/moEuuVHYQO0Jw5HSAUZ28z4DSPzQtcXnNsT2xPH8tjU6GqBeLMddxFkwW3kIAh/eCNC0tigTUHv2sMenQzqRbWX9Fg31QDBsO2DqEfP2TcW0zxXSFzW6niPHJZU3mV1UuOabLUVMkOCyhvIwkMtCMPGds5YbZZO4q1XL8IIdFTbEPtd5hXvhhauS4KEMPPpmBt6Tw4dHJ@rA0@a2gmAaE3crDq0erjJSgwvcoGDIdE166@nUOHbJk3QPTZ17yxWzkRmzV7obWa7lO/TwXGLm/rGm7D08VBFgQR3xJRcFPricOPVZvMFj0NWbpq9n9IXDLPQ1/fki5icnjx6mJue0WWKv6zp9Mxn13js@TgOHYp8ez/WOhj6AFtV2RguDH@5rWnIOyT@zaUlzEXOdE9MiTCcmDJahwj7hR4ZvFM8MZ2C2TsYD83Poe5HBe7eMvrAwk4/1c6uDLZdtLSwoatxsSy1sJCPb100X1ZMF30X1eWYNkMMa9Mnwz8LdNCh4rGfc9fnCx7INC7NCEMuKjRQfFkjLXqdW31KgZXS6aMro3i@aME3TFpXzsd6GemX5hZU1DTBPMOk557dY7jbF8EcJnRQfqEqxbtxnv6n0gd1n8IWrB8IRjM2Fu3iWIQidC3Mb/IVpj3Vb4XoElg6@B9ibLgf50rzFelm4QemcbRXnL0aGRw5YwiDjUqFInIUkJXShdiPgyfyULrhZrlCD4qmBRkVxpJkEw2DmABx1wxjiZDc0VpURYCKhp1LJpCRCfQIiUh/VtWEgj07mQ/Mrs2xgxFR2od8jeFTMkmCrOtuuAEQyWeYajoB/Q182NMusbQWIoe@0OjYkIIiftM1hP8O1jHisB71GgLVWY6uXo1K2pF2h0pOSzOp1nl58KJL90YBUxT3lwWurer2yGleU@Gr81C6xbDwEN3ueOR9cn4KFxOJHJDgsXa5G0iEdkGFZlrliLhB3UYtdV7dbwJMEV4f8u1y9FNdddoIHOP7891pCuR8psexbnt6DAkEdndDBdJ2LHR5vUFyDge6SpjZSH9Xjmq2UvV2h843r9IPKenZwUhSKxYRCULA84ashYSo43eBGDtQT4HOy4KkJz3yLiMNQQaYMpzfs2zDQavldT2XHFqkAGLqTQ31CTartu7ha20qzQ9YycYM8aXagzQk9xzkLRe8//z2uTo30O4hz90H0pBcxEiOqcdBIh5lhOENIdYDkjek6AiSBhawb/hB3AZFaTnJPotYD0vMGtK4EWs4oGq7qbG/3mCn7LI7KelDXTtlqJ1Z3n378eS1br7xj/Yz5X7@RSV6KgpM/AhbjyWkWgJSvkLCi3nnwnvjGmbw6knmEofILS8zuXPD6QGWlnMhQ/0VAY44zCJoNTheQpsWQGoXCowSaqZ6D/cR9Uj5IBGtekLozOmVtoyxKWlM9aGBgTRJq3uoqq4kh352iHPssDxGiyjidKx90UNmo1TdRdRcGWR2xt4yEQuiRtHwWbLwge6gtrl8J2dp69EBb5oHZHNLRjvOcmstXKDurjcp2lUwwKnFQDWPtxekol1VOR5v79YwXFOrp6eijbO4LKHXHhVB3M9jy9h8/uFxVq9m3bz19zGT5Kl7mB/CATaxePjl8sn98snvy7Bhq4SpgbAf8GG7Aa5CK6GR91@mRgksoF5yK@AD@E9omTBDVKCeTUvQMNIGKspYVeZUbI6xpKvQNweeF98yI/3UAwdOgp5TCfgGoQCdiw1LDzHM1lkyEFZoJicosn0YDrhoWDB5znMNLqahkVoHCUqCwbllUbHFmd7jbbUrsRizLi21nLgiWWBhfLfTnWZxbBFf/IPke6J73i@ebY1meb4JZkm8ADV2DMAe7hw@fPd2fDhZ08sR1K1t5cfifM2dsaXxSI1DFSDp3REDc3VORmUwBuFV0ZlzDs@lfmJAtwRyNPg9MFErpl6UJYULJVFDReF1IIYkEpQClGxREZnUTtK1RJIlBHx1Bd8mzGDKBAzlEHSRclQXmGCnMVvEJsoFYRXEFTe8JMXHBr@NeVPxJBy0Os4Z99NDjbW5BVxX2Oh6D/0ivFJhydTZiojvT6kxhOfj1TLsDGQ5gk2XeR7FVXhDyKk@7HKYXlRxDmlqvdFoGp@G9ONMPvXRPH3iBKBhjjx3fLLHXQ4f0BgXMJJQvSL@2zvWSU9VyTdukjwhGwSD4Bv0W4Ts8OK6gdMZFM@LvUZob2thRARBXDy40e/guqtLnKhe4nl5e5I7QIBt0lTRr7AmNkaGU4LFzy7NgSEyV0EYZpwecEnMjMo5q5kljFNvteSCTtKD7BgnFx64WhBOVDoLz0@CKzeQY0KQaioxpJksI61WuaxSFrvQCx@gveeBVgiPMXgRnfHtFUaDkOpYd6JQvoZJ5mjAtMd8d4sbtavxakCAJJTIpXb/fiwDOUZZ8ambe//oPuYLkUx/M3xHmUfY@2H5V2Npg/rXAR9PA9s9CWw5s3@W2FxmssutKZCfpnGgjXnh2HqjznizFZrOGrCHQr09ZCisdK/zzwyfMM1CnMlZpXx9FagsZTTBSYVYfaOOcqhrBeQyTmpzgSdQ@B0oB8gIyQSkHBRuKz3TrCdQoWspkMOW4Pq7SHnpzxLeukYLR10PUlA2yWKaQL2xoGUikch4gJLVfHTwHzBEmkyVgjdK5Nai8bBpse3ubyZ6h98xKocxJJLOqv1iXX4YJXQVYiY8XagzCQJBJCPCrimCJVT2lJTEo9mdxLY6sreVwigOhMEEGAEmisx0oCgKp0xFFBeRsmyOfBKdxMA4Cvm07ER3WASIFEHHcXPvzdKucnO3F9ZtIO1Wj1SA/R7BjBCvJ82i29oKd@qd2Xej1ZkB/P5pDwTaY/8kcZd@cDlER2nWl1IlZldKYG3bv2HZwKewAUssSuUxuPaMVkpHGJwtUkF5s8W8BJbRx4BmGab1yBt7u3v7hp0dPjq/p5yPI@CxYnMWr26lTRU3X6qEhHqZ7ulDvH2SOH90/CIoymqrJJA5CTA4uzCZzXmyzKV0Q@3N@jPp63ORxLSIte1vEtCtYOaCzP9exT3wzEcA9forzWqyJ5OVVrb5dPbVj16J/O0@DfExdQ@IC06lH@uPjs8nEJIY3xpzgjTGeGmgH0VA1CJ4c952ziaIR4RDx4OABFuAAkpoJoBaxT0jAEZ8BmmjEyvErazxifXyWiNSAhymKQJ4El9tg05oocBWaS7u61@1ZTQm68BaqMuZ6xwLFWqHGMtUb9Cw/kZSEslsQJlDRrLjiZlQaqbSpJpHEZk640myZMtQAX1KCRgD44k@GXpc9cQaRua0HZmB6CvIIezDkGyxM9umwD3Bt@jw1aYYZJBQFAkNBxcOk8nE1tCyhC3WUQn2zEF8NNaKKjKv9Vj4xSqpdc9SyOsDAE8k0tPSPNBCsQm0tmGnSj2rHgcfxEv4YD8JGi/SDVOKOJsj1mq5adsscJVDHW6kOEiq6xy@en8eBpc7SAOnl3Qs0ec4o6A0aou6LFjFRbjvT2LbCe21mFB1vbaGevD7u164wiPHYdx@CEfqnRLuvD1hiSGqzPaYysiZOE3ba890kU6pc@ZTNUikaV8OHPEBuRtA2mYhwWALnIROZCtQOunp2Cz9vrAGraapaBzNFkmSrOKe2B105zkYlJRgnQZASoa1g3bISpohTr8opD8Kgv0SqLBnqjp7jTQqPafHEwbKgXLPq3YgKwEkL5KW6tVUStTHNarYYkMV1Lq9mAO0cFhLIqVC@QpsIlBpeb4L34OA6LrCFe5@Ztm1CAQHN9HXog/UhEJmbTAd3WqUn12FwEYsn8ROhngQSOn1Nxn78sofbfFYzZZqeKV9Bn/ryFDvVtuhWx5n/PqNmypeJ1V5lnAFBJ1lNrHYrWmp9LZVatdcSqzZ29Xfv4qzO1SpIEg0VBkkjAFJWe8ky0DNIHpVVu7yqbydWW5XcGoUAKwzTLiHAOy@jXq7qV5nVu9BTp8HF5Y03seqRbuKsqmpXkD5sIauZNNDMJapypQutMPpVK5XCNKirDUzAu8zpcYp49ulxhiaQykIezXT6ornNcNWwJq5d58ULUDiLigbGnkPGLk55NQJg1PYULPHP8Vsge/CIP8OVH0aLzKYXHQDI0z63ZyyC38VJbSTXBM2VQ0MBjhJQiGhN68kkMJOf/SymFZicWN0prPfOU/F8tgwvrZxnefbR6qmi5FZrMRa7t1rXdb8BQ/fM2uXpg2LnnJntXOF1zWqrr4uVJ@mz@pMnX7xrvHsxGidPE/HY3tFbWdsA@E22Rb/bPpsst@C5pWLF2FpGimXWtLubmczLly9B6MWnVlWrAYhaf/cuWYvXa5uYp0WI4olcLnlsWVaGnQ68Vgt@ZafL6Iq5eow/qVRCIRd4KTXutrPTH7XRMNo1O53hvj7m7lZsiJ8DX4R99OXz58/R8Jwe9uYpd2cxjpEJuFJDz8dYLpv785@sXKUvnzS2//yb/Yy5gp8j/Hzn6hGaj7X8RysrH92/v7GRhtLi5idfPvn67u7uxoN0/kktv7OhZFe2/@xPV1Zyue1cZqXueVo9Xjv7Qs5lN2T1z38cbzx58jXPwwrDZ51pYMR3EX4ay@fZGXsDz1mb4T@Z37QiZh3NzfYbFnsT0zQtNqa/Bq404NC6Qsxn@llhWnVn87997@h1zI9Vc5nnLnz92OtYoRjjRjCAbT2wnceqsW0EK1zFxplKpQLGzf/2byF89VPAgz7jbXhV8wGuwjhWVSoU5G2sWgCDlstBvP/3N74xnZZ7NXjkjc2cvFOHZ42ebSlWHYFntXp4wHLV3JogJK14V7sbCWz7XRBFTmNacePoHlkt06GvjV/dhkErtB9Ny51yQuV0w784pxKbOHeh9KDWmRObBiWzcAH45zGiICAhoiJuFg5EWNzh@Szc81NdX9tMbeTu2eXn4gkNv7znKd6RWFi59/JBJrNdBWkAn1Lp3mnQCDNssyg7zj2cImQjLPQyexgWcFXOFnNyOp2@h/AjBZ9RbFKCjBcSi00VbYxNbCzqFGNBMDaB@VC4fXz@4t//xff/4nv09336/ScpFmzUU2rn9WrwAA3JVVe@PBXW0dQDTKr@lGnZj9/G8@vxYzBBE9JC30mOYrFqFV/0L2xkou@Mm/CphhaCmASZD8cEIwoKNSbF3mUyDKuEnQfZubdSWimWCqVcpsFmcnIPqknObW7J9WounzuCqtNkqritCBRg34FnBf7oH57Qiu8VchHOBHL9WWHVWz@zLF6K1WK1ep037mq0lm56nqpKGahPJUsjmvPYuRRTgKmlUk@BuJkgcnhOUzc@z1Kq2hBmNDjwdRTFAaxS7JfwVCUWu4Sn/m6t9m4tiLlWFYZtpV5NiQTBR23cq6eUq6ua@iJVLot/kBzLoQ0f@DD4QUbqV4qy/QKQ1abRxjeceMG5h9g5cnqrjRfbgD61XduuOHv0UxtYukr9RbW2PY1CJO7evZQKtXAPEFRX6ywJYqmirNQW5gEQ1hMMhjZQx1fbV9Wr2vbV1fY2/G/T@0p8wfVq@9o/fSbPApiJfx2p6rSWqZ5mRHuv1sGuZqroomZOwVCFL8BBryPFLpEgWa2u4FCrotS0Qr5O0gV7xB7xx7bhH36BFV3Q4RG62fxlc4gAJnTmLlJsDdhspqSt5dYz@dFHhf0c8CoPo87JcmYNDW@x7weRbUuK4Thoiw@Htsjh5fuv/nf8nb7/6g/ACvnEq2bJt/ka/x6@wb/XPv6dGPj39DX@sZM3@PfUx79HTfx74uHfyWv8223i30kf/@6/xr9HPv496@CfFKswBjLq6k62lz3PamfaGRgsloUhQjfb1VrAJ1nWZNlxdsyyfUdrgcmEvyyYrGybZTssa2dtTQNPMPgs66OpDZ8O/LUBiwt/VjaLyLPnDGLpIfclZfz0fdtgyVOpxuIvTRArVU3NqgWrUUfFXiBLlmOZ09MMl7ZZbqNMSsGurlijsf/4QaORwfZ7@sg5mvwfHfWj1qX//SPn0ZHTd@D/6Ojo0Slw4mrqXkq5B0@lmtoWn51YtbxzWlKQ3oOmFcts75xW1xU0F1LQWnLolvrAZ4IRvtWVUyl@Af35RZnEhvLFefmiTIbQyg0NASDAuAFClYW4AS4Q7vR5hsSDC3jOCS/Z0HgBnoGJGzLPL05RXIYBUvgPxRG1/gP8W//f@n/0jCVq9SS0gcur7QQ9SfxLJi@vLq/Eu5pMJIQlsQ1/6AB2DHJ5VUUjAV2CqZZI1pNXV9wN3onkNkdYxTi2qxR4AgicKRbGSfHyV@If9otxi@c0XgaJubKaEEufp6ejbDZZboJLuPqhv6VVtGSZ9hetNmta/c9@jLMo2k6SgPIb5bK2xs25jVy5vCEsm8VyuSjMq4nE1vWnmt3RCiDYbGwkk@UyWHYCnFmwBjiLgFOY84DS9HSjjO2@HEti@jkzSGRxSpZuYorLJfnu3YS4uGxnMEjevattZd@@DZ0ajZblNhrovv72rdyQcXdSZSsP9mzx7VvgQ/Gk4yYeO3xdPKFo7KNclWLYclzI5SZ4My2Tm8TZ1T3d993EG2uQlnEDvCcn6faEbNZxT@M//e43v3kar@B@FXLd0BABxsLy29uFjWq1sAHmQhEKQl7lG6ASndSWlrxazcg8u0xejceEl1bcTJLrVRz9WWyb7VSh8Xr4sMurGFUp28gnE82xmbwEl8BN29rijmyjkCimtsRfZSXJqmtM/OEIbT21sba5dg@HaKP5D7Lb8qVeiWcy8avKpV7CCbyrsiHu6sGzqvrdu@tbUKTFbPlUajQe7J7sNvDSYtygAP0wQ0fi3RIuPg/ceI1mW/Nb9Rpmr34aj5fK96jytWKexeJlAafEoRtgxS3eB8Q8T7LaeGp9RGhnfmuxAdM216FXhk5ZGtBmsc0sa@F6u8ucdnsFHKEKWRO3RnhmrxdccHThuL3WhdUyV6TYk4e7e/sn6dw2yAu5g929dO742f2Yhtb8xE7e62h/ur/74OgZBHjycH/3eP/jw8/3nz0Bd0965b7RTVM3h6bZuBgOL16zV5bVsKD0ekPLshzDhUQ0TNMcAFjwlE2TmYbl6a9e6e6AHsYZ@fsfffv9j/6H97/z3fe/8@33v/P9n371/W/D7/fg913@/e6/2crj@6df/bPfff/bvwOO/wl@fwy/n/z0q9/8Bv@R/U/g918ibn8ifhE4/pMA16/@9Kvv/finX/3aD@D3L8XvB9d/v/6T@b/vf2vxD8N973eXw3z338Lv9zmuAPa7v83d8HsN/rc53K/94P1v/Dv@/2fiD42/8/43/gRfwvJPf/Bn/@X9N/9DLlf8s3/9/tvfff@t773/1jfff@s777/1j3Pvf/Nfa9no63fff/8P//qPfv@v/@h/of/fo/fv3@b//Q/@6V/@H3/5H//yj8TvJ/D7d2D6yV/@ByDdv/vDH@H/9/7w7/74R/j/v/2rv/vDf/F3v/q/kuGH3PD//Mt/w99/8@v/@W9/6zt//ZNv/O2/@Mnf/vAP//r//LX/6zf/89/8j3/wN//zN9Hxhz/56z/@1b/65rf/6lv//K@@@dWC97eXvr@6hftXvwSX26fzNnhuk68Pdfnq50rPL1Iak1iATuiGIpYDkfj@2GRlKcuyjL@gnX7/n7z/zV8B8v8NAATb/wQ2@OcW8PoOWdgXXyBvjPqzFE3@KKkvvkB/MZz/AmyxKs3ZYS9RzBVTayAlr21thZN52xM034EQbzMg22fvvQUUX1B4/rAvAjBI228RGMAxARbATSeSYHCXLHf/6Vf//MfkEYZF51@ZQpkNnKPQqwj@NiiO7yBvmGQ3Cv0dZC/vf/SN9z/@x@9/9MP3P/pV7E@Uja30bhqkguVz5ACYvwUcAhZuAweAGo552QpbkXJgWNnGmV1JS718CalfARMM4Nak/DrYJK1KZg3NEDAFNsYn/FL4hn9pY4uhBVxG5ApflgKv@ylWqVRS0qiC04MIClYMM2LVIs5B4XxLBfBiIB4m3SjC2IiN7hMWCFlJPWWNtcqIB0yhQ5UwIF1J6PRU1nJyqlh5ABFWRg8Y4kLkKeklfF9WqsXKqIro3lESAEfqPkQJUBVM3aj6DuwVwgnw0ujBO0hKsZJKVYvgUsFMpii2dIPi1PKUOcp7iqXE1Cd8cbfqzj3GPpK1oswnSaEomYDGd2oCjYAADv6nqTWRHfoPjPRbw/BQTyMqH@7G/XfQmcILAMCrKLjJEX6Kgqm5B94jjipF0cInxTFAyaX4DBgLHUjISUkpqt8UWSB@SMMHP4ByuyrxDK2urkpoldflxhEMSmH0556VPF93cRGWpNASkwtbMjrjjrEgg7i1cPUJjWHXHqzBW4P//RXaB055Kq9Jq3GcfYkzEetHKf67d2@NfQRlQN@Jm8SU1Lqz4cR4drdTKTkHEVcdsK1RVlOECOcv6D8lvYhJLEY0AI0mzd/wUSvkzmB4L9JLDi8qEqYst66hHWdjh8MhhlDVtJpOi69KX3JQhUElX/FVV0na5Mdfe3hGJJin2JL4CItphQ06IER3RiZZUooZJopxTHrkde47IxjGpGU5rRVwJS8ppoxOSjlsxdJ@KQvvrzulUuWdtrEpwZfsQ7y7UpwmBXrqmq6pbm8jXVQvFZokQyPIvwWpWhX7GZgmVY/3TwD85IhpuazKYAh0ubGZ28hv5HPrhUJ@M6dtFLY2CvniOnDcQjafy2lbGxtbxa3Nq/nc6V46LW8W5O3qP7r2/Hf/aN4z3xUfqfoFG6m4MKFcSdVehW@yXcVtDvJpVi7T3B0V6Wotm8a/3Po6vCHJaS2/WV9Z6V0qWAKntLPzEjeSQKqlS4XBiPEOPEy6I7E74AQPxIELvUxszTk8KottGHgVN9@KIWt5oHSoklMgdY5OGkSf8pRtAJRweXkZ@UmxlS@/9Fm1CoMd5fBAikEb7rJgV4JitdSuShdGt4auSb4dxlrW5xbeiqO2LG/Q08dAoVlVil1dXbXDdTKy8hAtfF8Z5NIE89VIl/7/55f35HJKbl1Z1xRtHf9vMOTw//bwOfjP4RtCreekba4YqooXxzp6qxJers4SyctWpeUYdHCs3K7U6ioeqS@31KbTGqueP4ahuCCgSrzZc4yzeOBp4Y1zeJ61ktEzaqMBFOg7MD6nEf1ObjNfWsm4GRU31SfaLLmTK2yCy6kdOIFLHl1eTDttlVpqkKJH0FYgXK6UK@SvtoXeyCrkB9NVxVRcisSVbMc2r3AjdUlvAw@9NPj2o5Kcyxflcq08sQObKdev7vXNlqWz0yye27ucG7BQkK8COIgaR/c4/8ISfbwlCnfol7Kn2eSCwFkIDEmmlErbQhlVlTaU1IAZ1vGu3Fp9O1BTVZXevXs3oj1cpUPbF5u5chtFdGcSTifcBZHrrsaN@cLEmEXjCaoUewx1ByzcZg/xVIbvsBOH7/6/bxoLIPa6Ol0dvOc6nvcLwNzX7TPu9cDiqoxCr090vCHB61t@dwHEs0EfD9qa7i8Nw36/CQlEmuIA9@Hl9hxnHsAme/ZkQS4fhaoIcd8X6SIE8KeHH39yEvme7O/ufSIV2P2jxw9mPnkBlGcP9w9OQusm9w2C5kMUX99/@HDWKj4gL5Rp4muF5Tdx33dg0Zju67JcY6N6OQbF4l@BdF1u2cMt7e5d4AxPXDxbUWAb1WK2VDrNlq8gR5X7Z6UBbiD3zMGatz8aeFsbkEc2ZM@g1C/KqE9HlqElHuzuYcNLZSpxaAukcQllK4WtlmPF8t/81u@ZazYNFqRHuO98S@PHKC1PorPMeEst3kjtS6j0qOVc2HRCtNkbmmw4YAsd4YNOaHStTtdn/oUTAEhNXWfw@9AHwpvRx1/u4PM4yO2aT28OOG5zstosK6kkyuW2ivni1nqumC5uFTfyWiGfT2u5tLZZ3NwC8SOrFbVCMb@lpYsbW@sbIC6Bb35rU4qB2GC1MxmQUTVZhm8J0NoG3rS2jVfWOWq3KsX4/DR7k9CTLKaH9iGTTQgj4xW/nk@Ha9asipzbwJNvILMCRp0ZLHZwsJc9OJDl@2jBFbW9rCy30JIvZrOb92XZJJ89EOlysuzwMEXUySD73JLN3t@T5SFHgCoTZbmLlv0CDqRl2ULL3u7BAcbTRksOwwPYGffhll5g2QQwGy3r6zQSl@XXITqA2@URbVBK99GCcaLPAffZAz9Z/jhITzYLGJ5yOI7hkyCvu7uyfMgtu7vos0cZz/OkfoaWXXpk2QULEKEsd8DQwU5BlptgRFKUZQNMxlgHN7zVDrXm2dgUx7yAsIhkeUTQunEmw3hRuGM0n3zyid71W2aHP2OXf6HVHYKPNRruHzQ//rjZ6TTd8e7@x0/RZ2/vE709HrrNTlMEazbgcSAM@Jz1x7MPpPGw0dB7c30@Ax97xqcxbpiYtob@GtIkng5G0m/sgc8e@Myb3ufY4OkDaBOf@3343teb5BM85EPfUbMpl5FQUW0FTsZjmzmzgRek@7rhOmW0jyorLJ6Ip8e1QrZeJnfWT7DkJTAx9G8n6KJ0HGOBwH05ro0q2XplVNnMiRN6Cfl0lMtbcnqlv6NtgYii72i5jdSohBdrOO04iyvaTkK7u/Ym8RikkfWNkny6s6PINa2@k9OKpcLmi7WhLCdL@N5Z3yy9gWFXHMZW@ErWNus7IPdMgmxupvRMrrS5iUOy8hWUiA/9UnPom41GInFh6mfJJKYYe3uQxSi7bExZtcrtxCg9qvCEsTGEH1W0MlfjxLLXkLVQg@AQLyXmKDsJLIHRTraEiyIJWdsqypCETCaRTCJjQlYC35fPg9Xc8BMxTBn5o7KSwu8014qFpIoHvhpOu0H3urKXUcjJRgvpOZ7SJA0NwVZqmgzwStIJDjmxRyAZy2oCl@H6NkbSiCsKY3x@UtvckqSqGGY94RdNloX140/2VBh5CRvqJFQPUMZ1XHUP2d6UD9eXFzidQJ@nfmLiBmkjcNvjuhPU/RGMsFFQDjwC3VKq0O6jnnxSvlQauJDytZOzk5MvlKso2mMYcvKE4AmzMukSQW0NqMHRajG9UgWTjhIlpRKKIHlBxdGoViuNSt/sD/wx5DkI9xnvbieIDj2emfDkGwW/xPOgwqNRyV5N4B8P@@w@B6JDo0GwRuU@lG@2bKNCZBOtq2wUG0nVFqp3vF@5fzksoVR6VTYrpus6rhzDk7Y7dmVoe3rbfGK6eMjz8GiVtZmJxymN7svTfYTcQ/H6Sqm6zJ5KR0JXqs3ktFPEikWX@FpYIpd0SAHX/q5glJJ4kSy/Bpu7yhIt9X5yZ6PcStxnjSS4ZF@2X7ZZjhU2ynSHUAIxAUegksMS0ZOV6meAmOM9K5UgIYIkzgAnRrQKNWK1yEdPDqyrcqdSQ@i3@NpWZLmuKLW3dalalqrAYMrjmF7xhk1@OXi2qeWyhfII3LTNjXKXNSvNF6OyWxnA4JyVe1DtYkaCn7zQcRc@FBLgefM28f5XvsGS20q@wh3LhOxtD4SJhtqojCY1tF6p5TYK6VxhAycwCuvw09K59RxuLE7nslvpnAYyBcgaEB5@m2DfgB/AgMiR03CaI9FLyIzJ6ewoq2ppzdTSiexLq/UymT7DeSaQDanQkmnf2beBcsABCQjIlqzw1ZOp3Fov0XKYvq0QDQPTK1NG9XSXDax0F9E8NfUeB08qbH0t0VtNIMzqyXCwX6uXSiBtfg29EsrrnUJqM5t6k0yWEyssWfHM11TKyB@pFAYrQNFi9oZ5w34tuwL5hjaoXEFt@6vaZq5UG67WFA0ymH3b2Zarch2q64pJ8BddXAaxqwxuAR/kgtpE1Jq4DVDK7plQtdpWrixApIFgzAk5cSoHB4US8fhmLh5Pxss4qbkC7oKxEwuOQ68Qv6vtyCDqySV5KycDT5/w82tJ4NN@BU2KXUk4zGUbW1LsUrq6vNqO7pP8jI3HOsjf4rnLWCe1KrEMbQhSGzG2QiZFrdLs825lt/N0tyygd/ekWAl39U52XLJTrqVByaxE9kbe9tmuvuDfU9zfB7FKpAKsxuq0gcC0SHny53jwbYfFIVu626/lcuv1Wm4TunTgwwFoLqeVV1MZFlNpGydUh3cp8cKnTW2Z7VQ1cyrJMjEjvrWhmKdpUcjRuxg1f7Z3Gcx2lPA@i4Re4o29Vk@@e2z1LovrCh@UA/e5umIxvr88d21/OUQc7Bf@7GUuD/VkO4EDDMN94PfQx@bzMiQg83LgfZkrrj86PLIfuAcm41ttixsNuRpjWU3B7bhl4ZhvyOUYO1PiWol23w6Ot15svii@ePTs6NnRgRQ7XXm74sCY7t5KNlsqloqsXH5nf/o1Noivb8Shmk4rsVFlQxwi0apVRdvOsR0gbwalcGi3tYKSfVvlxFoln0IOvN7/yg82RttFsOdAtC5BaedTuWpVW8slY4P3X/0BniK@3P989yGLo1aXv//TH@c2//5P/xXtG4lflT2aUNyMASQatcJm7PJycHl5BQ/3y8fqMZ6ojc0kmPl@HC1WzQhnbVNLxjwlJma3N/Mx763wymXxCAL47h1xB7mQh8YS239q5XPavW2sIi2sIhb@bZveVkyKFR@9fMsYWIxqq9OxcmTKZFjpncK23ynb7B1Obb9TVtjLShVX0LRMhjYY8/nVtWq1imhYvJrKrMVZLg9@tatyPcVofhbGdi9wkHs6NYN9aoOT6a3hn4neZF/zPLAGNnPtlQeJZPmqxmB0mMmcJt//ym/mcoW//9Nff9t42/gCmPfW1lZBy8V@BklacoY1GN7RNBGeRkVDOCxkC@5HVg1ZiuGl2W3G4YNBIg4LUYcD14CFNuncsYSaowYUnw4yeYLA1vAkXpqkczq2nyxLUijCkvTtdow04WBrqBIeWpp0Kd1BL@j4WAV4nXRnggoc@qg6y2h4vaE7IEEyQeG0eprdhSAQwx1UtrJCJwgFw1S0MsusXQ/Kk8z1LpGowvqm56G2NWDo0h0I8hBImC6oYwMdT6EipGUDh1YRhNJJHq0axF2HuHs8QINcE5R7DpBmPHU8kA3SuXQHj9SR@A79ObO2AaDMktIdKADIQ0Igtupsm60n2aWVSpUn6tmucJsk6ubQgzNuEgZDbC082BkELiOcxVWwDF1US8ZEDRtm1DFAwnHw5bcKDCwwONlQHqJjrLdGBbhInUGCssbu3p2kqlKxWklGOUL8qJsOVcpNdGldiwCQBaOyj1olOc3sVAor@8402UGJpyi5QHUKGSZAbTxsiNYrSYL/WxMtUuRMVZFHGTMg6ou3CgOKDAJjsfM6NFC7npbbTLIw8Qak3aBEkZqecKh5OvpIJW1ZBk/ilfSzWKA@GfjLSXRAJOh29pAjg05siIptUYMDZwbi@CK/hwv51KEfhA5DQVasHkG3LReGFrRoGCj8SaxrSQzWDl0oHbQVMrfBcJdiPokfCoXQqBZGRxUrIp4Vmgkn3XTewLFJJwudbsfNnaQpz5O4Bhqe7KF9oZN2NR4LbX2MpIirrEPKJ41qNlcb5/GwuEDJL14QZZNmZkcl5UO5LZbgShBx5tIO0SUpECUYBpQ6lnGzZ/YhScemyVAriFfKZDogiwybpAbkkQV01T2woLewvYy4GTBzYZ1ZmRNUyqo4bZBvxbHTGIovVqiTS@jaIJV6PevM5OPcxNS5YY/lCmmQH9NQspMfFGwJp3HxbHAWvNMcCn6b8NnkxmI6EnYlMU5e/65rK4kG1uhbrt3Kxdv/znU7Ur70vJXE6NQbe4FSADqlCnY1ZLnQMvlJwDgeBQyPrEpCe0GFTtarOL8@SIDoFZxlRSOIrOY5QCiahH0MME0jOGSLrRhye4c6AGp70LJQb47vlvD0eQU1yiUMaHqCwdvsI7aek0i/IOljEOoTAAdWfWUaO/hBUMyH57egYlQ@RQF8BVpnvwV@MVQjxckPwwfUjWbSITUhb7Yi0GGnQ3FVGG8WgSUfsWDr4BoBIesr4FmAFM5JyUpCTgHalJyUOeow/GxwTu0S8ZISu44pzRCDKGrAgqLCfd3jOkqFypuLiwuV9C4NXUs1PVTW7eGtpplBxwKZ1cn4Zn8grlyy8OY9cavoxKRwFf14/@3OiK6d3bo75l9JauM58NdDyzUT8bYXxz7wHPVKd/qk0gKVTXhENwcWqaw3ErQ@7Qkyy9XTlwGZlZDMlGL8CpEwhmhG6XHaSAOydNM4S7cvWmXhwS9sB@RQWWbgiCoR3cDS9wKTNWiHEI5Pu6oDe7N3Zjg9B0UPmc/ETqLmOQwgx4FV2AfWCALZ5gXbdV19nCD/JEIjnSbGJN2wMfTu5ANG6E3YJdccZo1q4/pU8FEYHPqucFXWRYUW0uVypFxhG/qPuP8I/EfcfzSJNIi2NqpzyQudrjA7SNyooSqARDTjAOaK65ub@BBmkJCZxlEg5HjK7Qp@RoVCB@XNbVCPlYAwgCZIzWMC9UvWTuu2Z16s1VOZDtC0TAUBNQ6oa3Uq04tWaMbS7533Bo435WSj@ibofES60cnoCmrgtIJ5DCuICIOXl4Vafjp9lU/G8H5fZBgwoLgFnigB7PoJK1kO9euSJxBOTZ6UMU9YTSSmTkKW8BJuIBXxoucFG0VUjyBC9zBLkEzwYUHLERcwCCbw3MVbsANYhS5UIEXB8XocSnKmqXCWUqZKiqRKUYJkQrGjVFqZzUrgD1VRm/GKZPNK1H80@SsfnPw2tIv5qSeC5f1CWYo2FXOEalFN0VyoVFm1EqlXSEFmTe@ZLnRQ@1wMFZ0yRLOWCUYTPB7MAlfnm4hUvpHk9UNnWGRbLoWkMK5UIIvjCm@WvF0ERcoLPAzmiWDjgBBEeM5AAEd2bjBTBBtFg40qFc442GhBsItIIkeUyBEPwqFHCxJZF8FgkBQqjMXqqaOeQBCoZMCn8d4SdeLKzNPPUfExe4VafWDwFMQ54TlEBYKGUJJGOjPqc2OvRRIdYVozCJAQryFo8TufStIsw9OU0BbyKF6UAY/iNkEGnFcAgRELLnPNbYmQyGioC3K9nKJ@ANqunKpJsoabx@gvy39yOnAMftp1x@w0pDbtmE3P/P1SHOtYspEGGhEytOwGMmQcsOySIhsQSy4clpgjPIN7JrgvPNPsOc1MX8etGBk3cot4MhgPkLLKewPH131nY6PEB0EW0dczAc4it67wMYDVsR0YakR1Q1pcl6UdR5WdhtOxLc9M473lXAQ3absAV9ouReVeYXQ8SRIzhHxYiqg5AaHo2mjgTXWNRsIze@1kKVS8ilYV6TAel3A8C6ZIeOBDAunRIOE0X5mGn7wZJypOFcFOLOMscTQQnnGIZJcBszJAngffLogqzHMmI0HSZ4iicdNPkMr6rtN3OiDeobZSDD2D/nCCGxOkDwaUljTTcYhaiqiXpeaQMNJ6UgT97IODss9yCT0Zhs9NI5gqjDRzZ8sYS9adE11jYXQ8WBDf8Yen9zia3uPl6aVR9Wya@VC7wj0/LOr1xAQDAE6SsX5zMtJCOfi15EwlJXRGAYoHuHUSW7TVqYUp3QXQXQGutoE@0qHNI4VFIuGfLyr/5RUYBN@/bfXpeHHn8Rj4TR931CXo0gYvWEdMAPhhEnnP9ehC0n5wy7gAFm9FOUBZAeRVYlw2asOChjmAYbQnh2soAvENNI/7mK7RPW1uqnDPOWlyz9PsLLe4ih40WmZPH5uthIBMR/AGOX4KIzPiV7fLODI6YnoOH9QloJNKRpVpY6FzoNICktHT5xFV6tdgOIgVUg/NfFMKDxeXH/pfY804ZVfhs88g8MfjMdK6T5ckDMaDMdci2iN1xAEf5f0Pr0k8tntzgUA5iC0Q6Um0yWXs82kizNIteoQQVp3OMukLC7otpz@4XocfVkQ35xQqNxKoEtTylKbzRTVuLavxCFUENMmXem5HkjcR3a1pLkJqHNmEhe19WBdyDTNufTCMRBQjd1laY459jSegG8272Qt6lcYchhqGJE7nWzSuJvkiKeEQ@BC@OIH0OXwRYcf0G5yggrzhHJW4BIeRT18fRKQW4QLSOGCJlGJwnwUlIwIlBWYAv7wK4zQWxmlci9OYijNsAdNRRoAkYypKUQtYPcuqoGe2/QXcGb1wkAyfZWwbHtvRXZyWuIxb8ZKVZvHzeAkYctyMl/YTwJTjrXjpARm8eOmYDGfx0mdgmLSt@Nt4KWgWCOCClQz30F2wcLQb8dJeInkl@XjlSBCvGi@FdQowO9xKJQJFgfkGqRGXzGxHZNN3TejYSKhMM6QYL43jJJpwSdMvC//8bgF@Bw544pzlGgGzFNOmOo1Ij8HjgW4j0Dk7pyWXRG@@f3RAW4cmlzeAfwoGc9EwhB7E8Fh8mhnxhKEvrVDAFxKIfLM0P0VMm77h4xbJEbEDhVIlT8dPpaeSPNBKkH8NgOvJ6YsjRPigvqZR8Aq8XTox8KJ0XktOEB2lCNdYk3OShYX6Mr4kU1jXM7ei8NqP1hDNXU8D4b22AQivJUIb4ekgw9FiG0Y2cAbTREK@uCHQioah2TfeKJF6Z4IRVxAtc4E3OYucIWOINv7ksuxEwmHSplgQetaydd7Kwn6BeDF6TXhdRFLljQ@SEOE50MJN48xEsn0gjATH2U2a@opF3VAQlkdJnGuaTUJgFfWPDHWfxx4OXvdRK8mHDV@DkCOcVEkggkjIMBbOX50PkN8dLr8HAnVQCDMRzBOs53el18Xrpb3sTMp7k2ivVyB6ptmD5FzhKIxhUuQwOohI5sto7ZqIj1s4uJDPIw2xz0j7QbGFY4Ibym12bMFxoZTgnk87nuXA8Sy3uKCuSyS9czUQWlSMSeDhGQ9TOsna8rTyjM@rYvShiWy998EV7E5XcLTyEB9lwJ0pct7K8bgnrm1N2jYp9EUXZKlaiXFGTsufYTVPHIHd01JsuAwLDkeNpw@OHj/8OnS6m5ubSdFHjyfpw1aLk6phP84x07blsD@YM2zJpVGhPS5e0z3MeEf0yqktX@MlnFmDMIBX@QTkJ9p4UvCyCD@fabsQjsNGSlTgOps0A32KK6Goo2OXbYly9aFATD@xpgskgXgL5Z2m0VoS52SBOvBWwEaDuq9GAzcjNRqiF8OqCVa4kz@LrWSGnkvX7XJ12xeSROe22YMj9vyT3RN28sk@O3i29xn7@tEz9nz38Qmec37y7P7Dwz0Gv/3Hx/tsMqOAD15BggNKKNcHpmH2m3gtbza7wQjznjMYc76T2Ety92O9zz5xDBPXo7Y9vX@vyy2qbfpVHmofhqNjnMO06J6bvuX7/AI/A9CRcNOiQ264/58BbBPGtH0c8/adltW2AFbCse/AMr3gBBbrWVCDwG@D85VpLiThdSi0FYguw6N7DPEiPIDHRRpAo3uTixctjwcwWyoTBRc@H1yCJ/tPHx2z3ccP2N7R4weHJ4dHj4/ZwdFTsD75@uHjj6E8D49Pnh7ef4ZeBPjo6MHhweHeLjnwBGRVhifZ6WbDZUlQEZxKxTjDJW66dju0RWedAQwkeHah03E/j8WHNnIfS@9Zb8xWvCzhVUn8iCGtCbDwokJmvsalzGDNl/YTyM88uuxnNcu2KTZoLFVob2XRXKHbQ6XruPDQHzO89Mks06nyBJknl0nRppyWZTJ5D/ec4Nw3P3xObTlADRGtAG5EFWxAqTC6wSAeT28TyirEZvQcVMrGY@ObAoUFg94Lto6UJSoxsfcFkeKhgEMb54O0cugAdA8OORGt73IAth46cAC2wR1QFD3EvSAsLyCG/tEQ2TMrcIdX/cEBrf@yzdDhvk6j2KJIE683qlKdhbeo4FH8Ht1BwWd56HIp3TMsi4J4BI93OPR6wQ2PTRNIHniiuI8L96oBpAzMpo1LDWIbmz2khg2@QA2470dv@x5LVJIqO8HNPqZt8cs9Oj3d5luaJltxiPZYEbWPVMTubSu8NYOOWQwcIkC8yWY6HWG4B0IqNG8bDkLevxajLvY80s1LwZaymxJw/1oCfh40gEiZGukY1FPRWU9E47QFKSc8BygS523fReGBnFtDw5wKENy/@cp68yYpCjk9NU4K9h1S6qCK8KrSNF@zbDsutHFiq308tIJc0Og6A9/idZiYzsHk9jSAxo4NYntZqU7FRjemzsRoO3Yk0iZQ8YJYm0CUt4mVKJ4vkofsK2jr4fVttI8Ok6M38QrpydpZGheRLkycfgFBmF89ib0NXSQs5E9pwjve0XWgxUr1wf1T5d3LNF49wdkCv3At2ETIrw/tY1zQPGidjzYguih3iZYW3F/iDZsYWuypE9wSW3mADMaBXQvGdfca5dCPbx@@7o6nUWbdyfHt2woPpSBn4hx56HUTE@6WZrUgyjSFqTOx1yPCOyGxwOsTgUuacIb8@h4ePMFaKEOJ2MhH6OLf6XtDBAsJctcctoGziJvBRHWH@JOsSlsnAkGSnkS0PjIvEvcrqWoyM9k5wiLFmQhYdDrAjBeHTfafUH91Dd2D5eiAf98eXXFp6nj38EHYHizF9kFpU1KLcfFuKYLr9mjfLUHLO7efCy3kPb0YMe8kr2MLKT0kzvRqLNwduzzGl9fqjtoeoMG@F2dQQqSR2IY2LVEHalITPEAyimYiEB2fPNh/@pTJfHwCYYHv4ZChJdgg4l7h16rw3bOWTcxODYWmcLAcCk@By9TWteBZ1pjnFt4CViFkkLQoj5BZTF9jSlxP9CwkQtBuemKIQclNp@4y4EFeTSC@wktCgXnFJmJYmEFpbjZjvPOxvOimblFuaS4bR/fk045p3nfjdWTuOIoouvlH7@BJkfn195zLx6UgHi5gma@HlOEWSNJ4J6/KjiHiAQCq6nQNLqmWoEpx0zwXsGNB2eEOr@y0hP2LExQREhfCuSwcYetCOBZJ4/LxaiDm0M5D7AZ03NIpPPkOZfAIWDy5bEcrNDnp9BLTXRAImXhR1r0oVUDw@lU5vF03MeknK6FAHm1rq5SaWpDKOs7OCtzlxUAf4d7mwix7mI0KuO3SqJR/mKh4LzEVU1DmczMTeALmQj6/fhPu2VwEwZVfFDfvQ2b5p98fwPh@gtIbezS9D5R7@Dgd@E8IYEnR8a3yQYOZCQiizpw@ZSrv1BlF0wdp4fNCkBjUOWx08Vqw6ViTbDSTtvnYeY8UxU4g1/IQacJhRnmruVb6V8ujQ4Z8Y3wrHx4fb2wIhHsEr34WHq6LKF2JOOGh0mk303VtAuPHkvoOHh@j00hLz8zRoTm@oZVnBj1pmS2agbY4ZMS31aaDKQaKhGYVVbxGECf1yrOzeopWjubw4PDhPlsjnXXtqSlI2ZWTEZazYtnLEkCsl6YjsNego3gfeSX4QRrSAUooJjqUl6CySd6YNioREJZrdMuD2PYpWKo2W@ltz9Bt1ACSlukO7rsQkCZf948OkvMm1LPlqfCQOG9gJyBUWlZUmYKCG87jIqZpFLw20T3ST0l4zYHYILnk0mE9oxWzhS2Jcmen/XS/tlVPrxkVmUGfq9t9b@hetM46Tve8zXps8Ko5MsZvXjOW32DrqGvyLleVqRUqeG41wVC9SJFtZYlgRQJ3SBnpqcyYSgoWcT2ZTYbf5RWWJAONlUt4AmKGStlaP6BCPCnnV/q1Qr1iV7Llfs2ul/Gsnp@q@CktlUCHu9B5AmvhC/I1v45d6c@is62mfc7cYXMMo6Tw7Aejsx/Yv@MMl9izTfPltM1YuoOb1fAMiWqbF4nwSnWkTAnlH@kOHeLR8Fw4TRfjbEvLghRA6adBWPVG9B4npTtZdTjwHfIRESlIQuyt9Va6E5w6ytKEAYDUrHqQnG3CM4FJ4LoPdx3z3dCKxqUxDY86JiMoahiSuJ18Kst4BBATKo5e1eqSp5q60cVE4NWZbykY296mizSBpDyVJulwp4bu0sGHbB2NuL4BnwEtJmAUJJh7dHxDguyjXUMDd6EpKJ/Ou9BGd4kEQfTBbdzsko4jUfhtKABe8He4SKWKGUwhWIGcyI/60dwBqp@bHtfjKgKeguSVcgczi7h5fJUJctrxTWWE0YpiAvc7F1icvKzgETlQNLJdy0YIn@TgVCS0DC1sHpYlVSl5VfHTmwRLRIIpQbAAOFIUd24sDZzIgtHPIxOaz5jtmb0eJJqXxZ1JcaCRjuOK@FNh/F4N46yHief@yjV/Zcpf5f48URMoFfrvCVApCiTHLidwV0yegKWvxVVhJJuoUNOGChLHBLa8DNZTfadhTYCrYVVyqgw9tqc8lIjPizm1z31WpsKEBB7617i/oO@cqPkwlVOw96bjx68kKsikvbFiK8kMlaq21dvhnVPog2QmQ2kyxoNjfRPZ8UYpjkwKdgICGk7jU7OtViZYUlrAcajNyNXte7IqhImdxGwy@KHDaw1rThuJlBLFmaKCG9H5QoiHvFciKAgnEhoLWm41CDwWgccRtAi1EkTLDy1ea@CQtdkmXsFjjG/xFTT26cQFcLH5nnd4ykc88/ww8nQBEdNdkecX0zQ3wWMf3FFkakkvMol7PItxPpN4HJnkDeM0@ZHpNs5yr4R8IsooAk5xrdxDH1HSEwAtIN9FVYieV9LPMmvSxzqI0IOeOWK7OIrQ6TSVNHUeHTWyeqgliRS2eMPBoIeLiiTYXdCJZ6G4I5fH1ZQJxsgymiod4sYdDp9Gkzg/DoFUdoSYL3D/x8TDG3bwQm9ct0HlSMBacULF8lVp1x7z@QpoM@s5fircZEOPL4rCYL4TTQSvOd56sKS9gW6YqgSymAdSjsSz2ubtW0yX47EQ1NMFXVpJkr42tIyzvY9xuXZTy65rkSI7F6u9WXV9Y3JQCgop8MhlQVzNaxuSFFn6NfjSr4II0@whdvSfA22a53httLQLPQYBeiCceqZ7brZUSXpqhmu8iBdJGRce8di0M3QNPncDshVeN42nfb00X@0CCsMv9s98NdigpbC0hGtSk8VkqOpzq4UFGBwoaTu4@Pv/tvds220jyT2bX9EGbRGQeLeupqAZSqLGnMiWV6R8iaSlQBKkOEMRXAKySHuUc5KH/EA@IJ@Sh3xKPiSpS3ejQVGW5pKd2T0754wFAn2prq6urqquqqbzCIzqZ3xgpSs/AqQsOyIJEh0tS1hIdrlCOxNgA9OSGEcPGg2jIBp0YGbIUJUaQlN8yhF3NurOQQL9dYYeBvnmFwGA0S8xBhQA6qToazCk5Jn4z4JByIGpI3RPzUwBuF9AawWWuz8ZAPeNEUyzQtUM2GGCm6/qDdE4Omi@rx7XBDy/PT56V9@v7Yvdj3SEjefglCJWvDo6BO6iD8v5UPwIXljVBtS06EOq@uajqH14e1xrNMTRsai/fntYh9ag@ePqm2a91siK@pu9w5N9OlyHFsSbo6Y4rL@uN6FY8yhLvapqqbieODoQr2vHe6/gZ3W3flhvfqQeD@rNN9gZHtpXxdvqcbO@d3JYPRZvT47fHjVqAgeW2q839g6r9de1/Tz0D32K2rvam6ZovKoeHs4N9Oj9m9qxIB8AY5S7NYCyuguqKvZE49yvH9f2mjig@GkPkAcAHmZF421tr44PtQ81GE71@GNWNtqo/ekECsFHsV99Xf0OBpeyH8AKzMveyXHtNQINmGic7Daa9eZJsya@OzraJ1w3asfv6nu1RkWkDo8ahLCTRi0r8Noq6hraAGzBd3jePWnUCW/1N03YM07eojuDA5P8HhADUFah6j4hGL0ccLSApKPjj9gq4oEmICvev6rB@2PEKWGrilhAh4m9plkMOgQkNs1hije17w7r39Xe7NXw8xE2877eqDkwYfUGFqijv8VHIB3o9IRGjfMEcPEjEGtKUW6WplPUD0R1/10dIZelgQIadUkthLa9VxLnsJYLKcNYMgjQNuBdmQaU3t1Xn3zM6njX8rLYFqMTHO0d7ddgR5bpo6z4wwnsOptzmY/Mb7DT6I/wM5Fhpuu3r/utwagXYKyorsYGjquwn8VbORxQz8VZ6isXs0g7ClVIp1utd9UWKLqNVsvJPqZmAoyHakgr99dKOXKMmCkeNW808Lx8yXjfTiBqZ0meY5IfHp4vYEnG/hJ7tnlXviMKha4vq2EQPjasTEQhn4pc4kkJsEaKZcT7KOIuyQJBvweSHKiirZrPd1poBkXHRyoUhPDP6Kf4B28OxgvgzmzWKhRQiSUwBp991Q13QqkN6B@ZWWDQoy7zoe//2LeLZneo8@f7QdC1HUfVobIR6IF923mgetvvz1XPzdcnYOlUWSaYD5XeTSKMPl6WKBNyXvITGpmN/7Qi@uMoaDh3AxpFqSuyRUvjpL3E1dHhKCtkigqMnqBJRpnvdfVD/T1qc8XyamXu/Sv9ntcWugNiXlrY8E6p3jn9eXXOBWCBUU4NQMlAZrooFIw6yp1EF76BgpdYiDLw01596dO@DigBQfbaG5p94m48GUxN6IEPf3dcfb17cnAArBOhXd1c21ivpHSWrA9Z/vsR@6FsqZQkbAz7OMhp9MlYJXsg@NBKMVJsx@RPBFwoYEFMYq4mjV5ivgbtlpF0VEJGhsMN8XKWEXrgWT7iwRKUSONpStHrwpUpCcBODNXB0Vx5UxLxPZCViAakr8pwRrM2xX@wbb381RLXA5IEJEmMctQC5YJ2QXzPOlCeoKTcUJ4dLJK3FB1z1jWNAzJ1kXssBs/SL0nbxiyG7KmI65WmnWoCEE/noRDKbWLEK/st5QuRhl5K9gVvPkh6g8ePMh8dZafzwqgaNQCNB7om2qNjo7Mc9Kls@XzHhSlaWtI9bQu05jsSKFp70mysE3wYq4FAOUefQVfMNVzR@UDmuyQH128zjvjClIpJOLCdiqRY@Rsod9FwZCsVlQdE/lbZJQS3pZOVMNZudB8pVeSjzkeh0JlA06/CB7X/O@JkQfvboHFC6zG2jJx9j8Iktcq4AvWVkDK4UQcKxilGjE3z1ce4mVtzYi71wOQpzZTDZwAFcnZm6sVHylLYsxcgAIkcDRvm@tUeZ5ceqE7fWo6sjucho87V2BZyr1BbxZ12c@vnWRK7suoMBX84wmFbk9HhIVQV37Li1qZVDyrTnCovnocWN@eoPB6FZTKA6AVPVHrJTqnzlFWUq0zxAZkyydhwujrzEYilt/eezi0LI6NlgvfLEy6FKGh6B@G5O07KaR4I9r5NJkjkHOpNSlqHabVRTcbNR2aYa5Of5dDHdp53yRiCl85GN7hBDLl1yqwXtybs5@QHgp3EToVxWkBkt04eUEvb6o2GniyTSKEa@pMRJ6f32aqlSuQ5f4eE0IyGz4vX3gxAHj5u2ExiheVGkEXXROyMzRKyPl6w2wmCCYiOHo4bYMwOZk5evJdGB38UXk9kukHYzwYTaZFQQj90g2ITa@@0zXAedAItHEQYjNDNE33QkK58dADl7CPT3LqwgXgVje4oo@NgulIS9nb8ZRtwQllECYnbYl389BOXYoTKDJ8@YXAQauWCXDKpHzx30MvvJpj8iHs/ikCjrt/ViUSNJskWyJNUH1FKxk7EQx8HIVk0YCrQAqIxUWJDmvZDhT16Q5KTdFuy4mSWmGqURvLz@9FEqpyhoKOYcGXvQHzrOZhMxFJZZvLUuT1L5TUCZZHCdXuvMkbJPZPH08I6G2mW8pKFCPe5Eh3xifmmfvqIT9LI7z4PcfXAGzzLliIoAowyK56f3uVzBB8m5ns/8Cdd0yYKkkzXG6P5jVSfYES0qEyHMn1fx4tCfwYaQKcwmBaojZb9fXA5au0FQ68/CAYe6GmYEH3KHA8fZ/SIE9afBDch3aNDH7pGoe4sfub0MZxODX/rc8mKkWIrjPyxbbojRJNZ9ZKzQJDlHH38hN6viL7H87nOdJ3VtbhSKhleSu52Jadyb90XpUWV@eQeG5AMbmfOU4JDRCOKOzJiSyt3CrS/VsCAsS1ywnPucchLQLwFKKJjmATECpg77gfmIFAzuxfi0@4026VcghPMo@Tv@3gTTWjT66yHF7ACF/kGPQJeitJm0ajKpyhTzCeID7P70V3e@J2hBwB@BfilF4uoZREhEIvrqWRKIesrMikowELefwPi0cSJgYsN@rALDRONtqbzrSY/z@7DBnn4gFAk0@XdoUpckTYoPngJm90CltOaObipZETGobQcKIJUI7t4P8H6D7nH0uLHQ1y2nCFj2pMt2wbQ96GqA1jCqzXnvGdNkDkF8sMrplx@7KzNIdBd5FFm3PdgW0pyoQCTAe@veKwVTIAZW3PYk64emTAKxplHYu9e3rEww9oiXHcc50E/XyY2FzbL5S6h1p3h46ySmodnjmiSGCOPMqAhVF/pWZP5PBKnbgvXm9uaPYCH@3AW@0fpTUXPd5fXPm6Kn9BhV200ekkR7JhstKLfn7Zg4K37OYhsk9WrFnGMFrKM1owfjabm0KSx9HgMEfVJ2Ofw0QXMYb9dwJ05P/cidd4ZTqUuVZ8SySoRn5hnHWMygS@Ne@h8gVngWMLVTEoLnNPsjI7ySrk2JgvGD9wgSsV@LrZDsQU3nqw5OqJk/j27hd5CJeRE8LRjejjoHP0aYZREXxp3pMdDa5YrnVe4paluCbQKKvW1llQ4Ofw8bU2plTuogCW@ABV6RHd40@XjR/VrxwLloAWuTZ@lI28xi4NxxApAA/@Yn1pTlIHjrmTNxIpKLoQWsQZYC6Cl9Ic@q6so/Q0mTPHo3SCXESgQ/NrGPyuyBmbfXi9qbGOVaXeGRRyJbl5tjsjtcJWYoPg3ol8uRRZ1SXGFBnyGGOq7JWgB05MS9HgoQJl1TMpLACrnCCq6JVyW8JKym8b@nAu@I1JlgdU1o0RxUYkts43cwkZAsFhcJgYEZJbFReJWYKNbCItRYmPxeOISIBAr2meMw1TIWUniUM8cIxAeCVrNUU5LIluUFEwfV9ecxEdN3/R1q2h8Lc5/BfxoCE9zpfmvm8XE10S35XKyaqIm4MMxe018BFQ4JsCaK/y6/yjyxExdrn1CDSUjIWVIP@wRqlI3qLflfwjFNsVcKxlDtWcGfiv1q8U3oiSSq389kbqQaforv36wyjFVASIz@1PWORXKYrM@SAKrhTs9jgoVXZVHT6cfUCpt0BPvmgcHiaSu7ZnyM7ryJ2vFYhFpuG3msFcu1GhJGgSFZOlC73o4LIxvvp@8axeI9eMF9sMweKkUaB9mBNZEmA8mfb7HAWGAolg6J8NUUdW/7vXMCxPwgBLnDmaNS8pcB4L2n4H2eXnXJPsPNSn31wscII7vQujFd@OxnClbUadQUBs9gj9Z6vAM0IMveuiGrQ@qqDHky8qZCbYtx935ghsI3kNCk0VZiJ0vsXey9cofDoOseB9Mhl3MA/Dkdr7CwYFZochF8ICRYnevQ8o2mxX@p8HQiBrGIiapY3NqX1K3Qqj07pji/tjv16Zj2zr9swW7Cgx5BYe5gmmms8LqW47M@f6IZpkOAexHlb7yxnaH8DRfGHZ6uYDjJ4DoRSm7UPVJFHHIJCZx9nBpROpicPOUigGG7pAooFLS0/TSSO4prpFrnU1LPcRhkduQMGFGlcfVwECy348rfop6vccxRcrmzxP7V2eIdARAK1AuP8AnJsP@pxws64O5dCEs3@CdG3f5DlZoYYVU6nnH/cuNXa1WxbPxyoqoVnfhIZcT1d2q2McXu7tiH37v4u8lt7y2VmGeu@98gZe76uWt2IU2yMC50rmc7MNP@OZiVBg6a@MUPyu4z7KVZy13e6cSFk6ruxi0D0//86///j//9h@Fqvzxn/hjl36c/lkXyufzhWedL8@Wbiv4@3T/PPOsffpsfJ7pV5DKkN2fTEJv6Bneo/lO6oEIqe5w0L4vakp7zwxCctVEd0kb/nFd0MB@@omfzqL4cRI/Yk7UuLo3HF96VF1QCztupppZWoKnbTfzzxmyncj3nn7/Gd4LB3k5JU0g1OK9P6La2KvXzbTjyPVJeu/5mCMHb7qU@XLkwdVFWl0LmDsV@bw4z4kLDR66ebS4YBJEVjMZmH@RQKrRkU8OnV1LtQEPpcn0zeZ4Ppi6Cvsk3ynTOV9@5klN5Xn3JZ@hURsrwPCwfIV91WXcKw4fwMVjLzd3WlpfO8@l0@mUvhCt1SE2R72NqS99QZY6Qqf8DByGNYYlA2OnC@pcxAU0iMhIp@m6rKUOX@tmj1C1Jo2JFe50xpDn0d5EA0lpNscWbk6mgDIWKnx0BZkIrykKA2WD2WPP8AAACq/bJsYl@KrkcOx3Br2ZdnnAGyni3mGvxJC5ZdG7EzEnrEnbkuN62osbBISgFEC5erDR@QYZeQGUHRC34zGq3yBu3CWqC5n8W6zSBGuHoHEwnPWH0JlNrlThDXAnwLwjJ2s4UqF02APXbPsg9fhyRfOExb68CHfbR1PEqIMnZHg/1BBzcrHAx8e/lI0S1gNKOPJ@uB6GgtjDETsQBT14hA0fo@j4CIvIcAW3VElQqNSicqzul5N8YHnsOGLMJRGr8Ds@fCfyIBMk6cPyojuZJoRPY8aOrIlvtyWljfFqP1SkZW5QR64ki9aKPn0DqfIKzyrxnBKQgiXzdJcYsIaZuBiOLvT4@XQzxOsI85bqkrsps38CcCzdjQqXp@44FsBi4yrdPIYnnPK27CAMB21AFgxRThOlQOTggQm0epZJcWeSWvA4EBGMr5bHekWZ41Ok5E/HFJ/P8D5B0@5IUUGiIB6Q4pmYj2d3mOMgkCwPfo2CUY5YbtuPBh12oOTenypePMZzcTqmJMDu7wiUBw/HqSeYejhT2YXkcTFNddwO4QmDFXD9X2rR2yOcSTOvZNEycAQA0sShZ@csRlLcoqYEaiCJFAkj@X9LDD5JEObQ7w@iRJ2szMDAbuc8iluFelzkFwiwid05zGKghDpp1izhQuJbuWYg41XfgNFuOjL4eRHtqcHgrsYXT@qaPCSKp9u8Sx@aHylwTKhhBQP6cPlmkzNEmyvudZREDlN5dpOkKuJZ@GoP1LgEkfnFMgX4UAOSW8zjJHcK2CjPYQPY6dwyiLlwMdG8QcBI3OZOTjxqDr08XSwS3GHeil4UpEgEtykd0vPl/7vfxFS2JxifDIsPSiEdwB4dO5zoPBrzTS5cgTe@EtRlcjxgjZNrzEjHjixyR8EUNgNepEanGo65rtTQ5QznSFIaU34U@HmaMedyrqoab1z7PFk7l@GQri8qsMs2JJ2xI@O95NcnvJnDbqra5YgtOnqjX7cqtExGZmmHCTU7EuW0vXo9RA86xNAdS3pybheRhtLhFZdXY5aSBQiXicapLTqikeVMn6AFSGJfhep1FNSj316mp9zS8qxPv6TrVkEu8EAMliKC5xTkEzyi97HzW6kFyAcGwAjYf80LfXhOpVjykBqm9Trs7wZTu5g9s86sbGl9y7FIT9ZyWLoTgmaU7vicLQ2vbJS6J2VlJLv2J59Z@KQ96Hb9kcrFClVlb/pTSzZ7iub8L5rdhXzDrUVM3LcMXh7mYBLphcQ1PY8nXv/Ko8c3QXPizeqwCdHPoxHPZwPbO4bNCO9koi/HvEarXRA1rFvUk2OaeNQQySvKA8mnE5FowJn4DHFhAQL8OwjgPvX4w@RgDTSY42fbhZaead@ESb1gCSVkJ@oLPji5SPGFv1d4I22L3wFt2saNwPKRPs1dUy1lBPygHISNt1yDRf0hnvT4o8Q5hEodLAmPr43mWlkxBAItKpXr60MJ2B/6QkMfXkjFJupctq6uh9FAjuzOsNS4sNL83cekTqrrqu@5/5hMhvO4M8aB7Z4OYJXGugwxqhgLUglTrRj6o0I3jZ/MjrHQIFUVTvtRXiX6KN5WvjI3LN3vKFUDs3IYBzZKOcVxpgx1A2pXUvE@K/SonyaUD4QDkIJgLI/p4mlizbfmHOMMY94QYiZ6cv8aOvvfspLLb@i0IcaS0kuleybzsFjXp6iCrCjKQ2xDqwVK4ZvHgytfarZSnTCUV@PWOE6m@bsrrA9obgnpz0CV8to2ZZeniYWWEA6Vv6aBTi3E0M5szgKN1RRGTEmCWM5YJkZgPMuWbjkqfSHbYKUESjLM80K2kpj0SBewN2jizuaZ1WLEnU@Okt60BERFgaa6iqnK3S3e2KS/L1r14h1MwZqUKU2RXcQbaCyzLlDCNRk8iCj/LqJKvwxRDNciPPGX3wxNSQQksXSbSi0iX806pGuWudZ1BNEdvkSIe6oF4bk2Fgi67SEmDYwBm28OJlBJ9ltKGF4W1T6wxaQszI7hXvyOtR5WIMO5kHFtiOMwhOsJJtVNg3SVgv8xwTFwqSs06CQsICCyFlK6EMWHITYI39oaIVMWiELaSUmfoUKarwkqbZQc6uQRPWEE7q8Q75kN4lFM707wG24oJHIsi5YMIHx496O97h6zdGJ8C03SwJFjozSz5@XxGIMKHrJSF9IylYUtoHnhiF9ooCZbSZn3ILTzFNKpJwACSxqYUw86o9or0sAb@jAMnZGTzbmxGxbrh8rQ/UeyfyscK18FSQFaQCgq6QDlM7oCmidYSggUyEoLNPM8zACqdezMwl5iUY3ERUJtgpLVDl6SW/VCg5CeFdqlQxHfoDqJDKviQqupshCJ9MJqwsYUo2jNoKMjv4OGcG2lCh3DHizNDgVoW97IDWBxoKRuMsGuzOEsLQkJG5ms52SMhYp@AlEMRwIZZyMZbzFHusCE8CUhXm4psEy01DdeaH/gArJEvDqXFgsiyF5jOSS20BRivF@PNOYXY4eqfg0/FAwRzMUbEU6Io@rcLzE0qZ@L0Hl8PkCkZND726HSnzUTjyVVeW/3fbTIe/FGifdic@@ZhQW0NuDug38HHY7zpcDSeP8Ry2bw9RPef8lMAf8wgVK8QqSTCAC3DyNH3jX@JNbr8mHU4mvTNftFPU663HW7sB0Ds6WApizoiRH5IAkDz8rBlhIM/KwNUynp3L1khaBiIijzmpmsHetlghQzQ/1VWQkIUz0Zxv0EmiP3IorkxKOroMN5AWCDwu89ygpAem2J1SJUiLjiKf6UMZVPepymsCdXMo9ALLdkt3IMEh4aBMtYuxMvepSIFR/JscO@GGGSKJCy5ukwzKdE/eeLZI@Ry5YfLZell8mmvRyLZ8vpMcgWL35hG39dOS020EI7lobcwoVKBnxSOQDFMEFD9DCOjfmSa5lHbr9c7PuH@PJH3RiW//Diy7JGfycpxCzHQkxnoRATF5C1Omh4o3q6PLEHWLYj0pCXpdjD/QXJ/mDdqP6Chf3xTewiLicrB9Qtvl7QbXQTyBqaUGWHZH9c2BHyWl7TF5Zc2xfCvrugeb7jbfjFP7bhv@9tuKBxgdlGH9hpjKn/x9z/Pcw95q8cbhY3i63f7NxXv7NMwrLmzluFsJ6K0s43G2fT/eLZdGv16C/pKL1TLryfwN8o/Zf0@maaH@EBfr1Qvz6ld9LbWGz9Nj0ruK4Lj7KV6gG0svO9bhNLzbbhn5011e76LL2Tc6n6T@mddXgolcsAydm0tnU23Szi/1bljyR@mKcrWvi4r9Ux5bSRGwKfBUoXeVLLgzBucs/YHepIAkodTxpIceeHRnMEMDrPTMubRSmrAAFx8odPvrx/S6XNkPIj5Y@JKKMJR1yotA/SV48rwQrQXTjwh7qg3V6KXnHCCZVrAqWEGGhx8Ty/jkfXFzIHhQZA55sgMZNduUG9sKljTG@Gf3eK31g6H8VLK5EEI3m2KXfFTbkr/m9ajGfRZTAqL8hqnxZ7MF2RL34IGZZwNBiP/Ygl/r4/8ieUygSGg4IOXrPXwUsJh4Mf2f3vpWpcdKih1g9hi2NzuKH8eCasZ9/CyhpckVb0GValesbzsfVV9QsYN17YhnEyKrqmP4gur9t0IUFzMqtHR5SJooBJzSPOSlEAWa5duPLQcYDS@IdAYlAC2MHkelSgi91AYMNYGcy9f@X9CKDhZbIwtG4LiqGx/0ebbm4N/TGFuEx7PYuuSfKH3YY/9iYeZ6xDr/lrr@/XMRMPTEZ4aaHylBZvKLgmMlMTa2WJMA5yuLwPK8fZw4j3hxkV/kmoFQLDjem6Hgvj1CUTIt5t5SlqAmpZHFpAV4T3giCKy3PUuK5AP5M1KB8bTBKHhuDhYDwi4OY4/hUFxIoQ8gXBEf@UncYvqCOCZiIGeI0GjsofXV8R7ehrbU9LL89lzjq3ZFwvTh6vmy/llfKWhQjFaZLG5tImfrlm30s6l0zJ1AF6HCBYMyRQkCfkmk4Lr0BTCMOg/QMlWkKuBAsS6S@vvsllT2708IjG7pHf94hX3LQxGQ@87Q5CKoA1C/3PILszirIJUm1f98M8rwUKrBiE4bW/trG5SgDRjq@KdoNOomi5AC1PvMmsQMBdRldDPYqt6FIM/U/@UHqvENiUzpcXJdEZ3mjmXQ/JrWXdIdIBVCZGCliwt7L8br92cFht1vazIKasYfGQwpJ0WdtALn9eoe@9IWZqYDLCKrx88@31VSZyO8xmvkWLHIP@rYn2FRNg1UAY5nEPGIztjEvVpJ8FNyzGqLaP@ll9HE6phlTWaFxuCMo1XTVhKeSqlZ9OY0hXiH2lkQQTiQ2gDg5MRW5PhsB47hS6l1cABiR3a0VAkUPkn0i51vbTXE6vqZf0lAPGmsvtsJHF2hsOQPHMHF@PEtw2Q2vHExlgcnj8z6ztaYb4Qt6qiEsX9fhKxy1WdNzeJ/va@aKvpO4hFDYjrhnsztT82dcyMs0ChDjk5axCJv/7vzJO5TZOojO0IwevXhCfXZU5Os9MvcZ31dqZsAOTFUG1z/nIn0Z7nOnTjSq6QjvozvKUXKu7B1p11/5s9jG2nS@wV6@sdFz3hfMFupyMMQPoGJih34QWnQq@6yXe6RCxwtnZCC@gXsbQvQ@vD1/BlKOfmB9Gp38@X35WyGYyjlPBIXguxfftH71@i1b@iZMna//BJLiSeJl4upM8zPZVeFo8J@izFg6tgKsQOGffj@Tow91Z0@u/AWnJzniAAnRLosA4mJTBtifjyyrom4QyF17OYuLItZKTazlf@i6Vupz4vQrbKm5D95PddyoR/Lk0u1iDLtxymVqPoJKLXk1zWB@MYLd@1Xx96Ga2PYGtugtWRWalrYkDCIUIxsZXVbyOKkE6wFWIqiKO1iOCgf9WMtZOcizbBW8nU7m9vReeQ86nC8JPJibgrn2dlRQ3ce9OaWUSU8Fs7Lv4gre272pNKwt1MQULvhzh9jYjpsVBrK7qg8kNOQVtgbMGlnHd1aUleodVrkPXLReLDmZEuYXWQrw/HprlhTWp3E48t2trRHrjwYLbksr5coEDWcJCab1cXNv4JpjAFuHihfRLIbAQF7WWT4NotgSyoe@qm5eWQE6G3dR9urq8eTTY/dOHrcb6vt1pf1@ystYPIbntT8YmABPvJs9iEfDYicy1S0Bg5GLHK4y9H4PCarfYAcmztNH1N9b8zeKLzc6a/2KrvbW11emtbra7WxvexlqnXcBk71QlfzUYgZRkMfljt73HdXufYLZZLm71eqXS@kZ3bau3VS6@eLHa3lzrFldXe5sl78WL9W55s73V/rrUFsOTAgar@C7uHfMc@Pn9wl3qDm@XtZ3/Aw)

`k` with a negative argument [reflects](https://github.com/VorpalBlade/cfunge#undefined-behaviour) in cfunge, but passes through in FBBI:

```
@,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;@,,,"285_";# k-'1:,,@_
```

Argument for `k` is created by the first `:`, `-` next to `k` is just a dummy.

Answer (score 2):

## 286. Trefunge-98 ([CCBI](https://github.com/Deewiant/CCBI)), 13300 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^xy)\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                         7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsd;oh #####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&           nthte \#184O@  nthieo  nthneo  anet   /112\    ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}             @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 ataw;#8;""[ x]mint}=>+;dnu91&&1Prers 6 4>80::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*sEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:2FACbody+/='d  #  +- $在e*n*""; 16 ""6 
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀ )<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}} #@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;@,,,"285_";# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51 @!00:8:8 ;;~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 :  Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//   >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*<e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2AAJVQIEECAIE2Gw2eS/v7W72NNm371wQjS4UCkA1gSp0VYEEms2OmfHurMbSeuXxWDGakXVH45VXWjnCWodtjdaSHSG9OhR@0g9ofWxsKDY0/2D2nJNZhQIIgOwZTcQ@bJGoyo@TJ79Onjz5dbKpe92f/SyGD3vi9MadnuMz3/R81nKtc9NV2f0xu6dbXj63LkkItet2hn3T9r2SFGMaY7Z5wQ5tw2qBG/OdM9O23pgu@OUYG7hOx9X7zO/qPlgsCMUemL23/bc@M5x@X7dbHkCuM/ZEB8/20DhjetPzXd3wLccGrw3Gntk9vd9s6QwgTHfgmj6hzzNAYZxRmGmfAmOPHNczMXrD9DwHHTcZ2zb7A39cBUsRIHTXch7uPv54JvAWYx/rkLJBzxzNpEXLsueW6bZmQmga@/zk4GDWNcc@UxybHVxPn7bOnrme3tNn8W@w3aHvHPqz7nm22zFtneXULTU361lg9139WpBN5pp6q231TNWyDaawrtkbmC5DF9Z2XKgy3@wVs8VsY3cSUjUwbHHiOYO2EjxMdzseeDrnJhhNqImBZbZY23X6TLe9C4hJ28pO4BHt1jQ5GJBAIDT2yoPQLZN5tjUYmD73hOyaLnlDzKxn2WcSp74nrtMaGpbdATgTynUw9ClPnmRAsCobCBpW0cBiVAocDJJw7PTNaF14QLyQam9gGlbbMnjhmCPftD3Ir6cyC@ruwur1WMvsQYAJdiPNPIcNvYhTs6d3VUOVsHAxFtY/6zGLGYMB416QDUjSQbbIzL7zymJvwL/X9dho0Gee1Qdv33DabdNkb8xBF4KzfosZY0NqORKDxxjM5C60rZoAY5uQw70nX4ey87FI7TYkr8WaEThIC6Wbcq3bDhShy2y9zynCGIypBABNGKLtOCq6txzTs@M@u3DcM9Y0DR2zjpF5ZqetD3sQo9XGKgFasDzWd@ALFWkzSBYE9rE8EDdGJs3NCEYTVLE5gMaJVewgyUB9BzV94epAI64n6tK3@kAhlh/3mKl7FnItCOKZdouoYxDyMwdyG614dm5B44OiGLqE2zNdIn/CyzAXgFIP6TVx4Vo@UAXmYpc9MXWXnbimmeS0anqGPkBKjUYJkTkYg48ZUYk4t7fj@0cHcSBSHkLVB0CU7vrJ1z6VdKZW2GqjDL@KLJel/ccP2OXqKZo53wRCHrgJPckq75iXOT014TfSmpmOeyUBVglKpccyzsDP6MoAEqj4kMCMjkY0Kec5ddCLRMy2Z@og0nQ4VAtqAxgB@zxNOTOGroscflKo@hlkuufYHShPyKw7tHmVF7JQBUB/LS/NzHMTaYDXkXNBJXzSBQqBfwCNcBfe6VCBQrcDzVGUaBCv5/SGBAchPR/bJJQKBEWMh232OWvrVg@DgD@i4ql2TQ@IE8MM7RbWfN@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@ftICsKZ11of27o6ZYSITAW5i8h4CIxlSg/JAmGVOm2WVXD4/3WiutRnfzewqXwLXfZNZ2jQw89HWgZyDtUF27ul2Z6h3oEk4NgTRDcMc@ILzQE48H3jLbAdCjoroDVWvK63em42beoVA5pnEQe2Hak/0bTqyCyGLKyBooTzHBXzWgkZpUDOYjh0Azmcil18iyFQCXsoLkhB06UBkvJVD4wYCvuha0EovKHU2Z3S8V5mNHpyisQOrVtph1JgYrXo3J6mZ0AmTsRCFgjV6HQ/0loiqOuVAlR91WI5Z9/pzEDthEoGzR1zVjK4C7d2As@/YzhykUJAhWgSZ9uH1AKLVMUq60BMFchQ11lD8DasI6gy4BrR8oL@u7w@8EjB@y@8OmypQSubEHR/6RzYSS8Z3x5bvcHOz5zQzfd2D9pkJYsgYw6Y1mskQuYV1@MqTzkGianuswpD1AtUl4m0P@Ca57yFwxEsmKYdQ8LcMgASkQkEl2h6x4gNgKsdj20jIU0Qpp5mMbVdOggEDhkXzKUpj08l8BU6zqUSwaGLUDEJlPNcggxIRMhE9glOypDtTWbtlGqU7sgyvtt7zTPjaw14PrUObc7kE7/yT7FK6cwdYW4Kis/qDnmVYfoP7srt3hZDAVmDghnJQG4WgJIS5I0bIKjAUgBG9D4dWfeeYpNdEEjJy52oqYtN1HZfH63dd6NTJAcGkaKE@ts6GrZlStdENi1PGMQQKyIYPEi@Mr7jcM0ME0yU12/eyOJYUkgqG50yzwmSBj6K6RjrkijUmi2BCSKyIpEWqMIEpSnO8ADy3tHho4RbN/J7Tx66NPSfxEccDMFC3bJywkLhYQVKFPleqCAUKkv7jcfWVY9mJy/jKykq8FK@CuLCysgOmbTTtoCkFph0yKWRCOBVNFCJNJvStUQh0q8evagHmUbKOvGCEQ5w31iCh10ql9Xpar2nim8NvEogMukuAVvADeOLJSgWNyaRcvYCMqs32dO73sMs/NlxrIArhU/1c53ZRCutUDEC1jot1UcYyX14m/Yprqh4MbYxuwo2f1rKn9dPL01bq9CqextDJsl5pQqYgvkRf7bjOcJDIJmsbJUWrJ5O1dRDFmpV4Nr6WSBQVGJTCuCr5UTGZ0nlpJ@ImiAKJ09M4FKoon5rRdQnfKJ1LJsOignSgtAcjh0RcvSxC/M1kPZmKQ9hkPA0D0Uo8DiVjYCF4lGmk/KkCOnr6GS@YvVRKIgKFMTb@rskS4IZD@OngT4Zv3iDj5jiaIYX1hjofDw4EQObQDmBV9JwZggdezTbDTmQqjo@dNh/j7eFr/@GBZI6otj4@Oth/WqFourp3BgKV0kHYjOeDOKG7LRXaUW/YMqV5MMAzwWRMUoKzIRh5xzCY4jACUwyeiEhfabAF2IDR4pSA6jCl15/OgteF9O5N5YGQkDuFXCa8GUGSOPjcNIVRHkB3tXf8cGrSr38GwhQzvB5OfiguzwBYM2vcsUWfGLBD3XOsVokd0ojTBukaaAuE61Y4s2E7toIdQTA4daIR8ekdgCA3FDVRjLKmYBBx2xrBAD@Gs0Mo@@EADEgIGBgUmA1DbVN9TsxNZsAkcf4NRmLzhkJPuBSpGt6kdcJoB4yDnm4AC59GdyqzU0AIHCiTme@TLF9DDCOjqYERzUrclEeQIw3dxvJrWTTqHlpeF4sXBlLYBbptKFUccuNYkkrtkBkg4negpM2RJfoiaOHHGOQT3UskcSy6ywdZSGU4QMBEBXORJL07hjF0TRgooC@f/GH79rnlOjYWsroPqIEVlbEOZpDPK14go93dw9yDxeU7DzmU2DVnLVK2UayzhWt40Lpsp@d0HLYGAEiaqsoJ@9DGOVvotH19AC3KekMFtNtx7PEMDZpmOAtcWEeS5zNTCJkhePUV9AJsfqYnAAvyfHz45T701lo@m4X0B7YsPWEmI1hm84iOBpsAiHWNHtIN1uSX5qA7dqfIyXPELJBPU6HUMPm8nA7yM6RKtPA3FDTayLkLtPPAqxWY5uV9nwZEOBU5GC/I/ZTwwZsN5DA244yuQVFMIb1W4ZP6RcZ1mpniW0HVnSvtvuPrmc9VYNH4knB4oFhM9jLxlXhGUfAtkxfLVVmmZZ5nkEtNMI/2caZmDu6RaRoZ9MXOjQWGucUTeC4omlN4bHpBNvk3KIMw5Gz@O6kUMnZKXRg3TzR08ifdoSmZRtdh8imMr6I5k6GD6FotU4GSB@kXB2VhMLHGJfnOEMa0LbNn9S3/kFYhejYO3FRi3ipyLeG7B/xmguCJZcJohM@2TDoZXCmY9FF2h8M/BU5OWD2fqbxIXbOVWZtge@Q4bhentjSaUMmFRd8XHhnHG7RUfwQIeKh96t@9oJ9/fPRgv/Fk9@STSmbouZme1QQe0TIbfRjJ96A5LHgwbTjfuQ@0Y9lO34IcBSjfnPWeOo7PhQdcCrndE8OAAY6HDxoPD@8/3X36dZE46tGt/rCnYxpLqzMAIY5jglmKxnCaDsgW9nAhJhAuju4fPQywfPrs4eFu48H@k6OTCJpXw56la6PM4KyzKEOfIgjT1Cwv@qNea3qNisboU1MogtnggLPMYGDOFAXeCrrxSHFIqqIHisjYPSoKzmnrOGvvspyW3dpqNfVi0Sy0jI2NzbbebrU2clox3y7mc/ksvDYLWyZ7S@CKYo5o2gpMfEoIZ88wDkg8fTR1I5BwYBxugMQynpuu0HdJ4ox83tzc2NK3jK2tLT232VrXc8VN0yxstjeyWbOgZdvNolZcX5q4SDJQtJrY@jT9Ba0OZ0rIE5hfAj5TzYEnHmS9C9bK5XIFI9/eWs@18tmNVnMrmy@2mtqm3twys@2NdS2ntYycVgrCAo8FxpDpQoWhVGmDaBp4KRp4JqWgM41WMa2bBgvrguGsriOLGQQL4zhwEB4b6DEUy@KAM3DPo3uwKI7zU8K9gO59XBKfSLJkDR0FYJEAcWVcdZuB4xY6hmviU6vFwCoF/5znvziQwHypZa8Q@QWuqkfyd6lp5H7ut9tTzjlyPlOwK@tNnNfJma@pT69mi8xe85oLHOLbIHx8LX4uvmtec4FDfHmOD9fw56Ob8ZkHGiIrEDJc85@La8ZjDmCIaZMwRfcJTPyK5Ldok4CIa673wkAh7i3Czdf/G6@8BoraDbH8j9TMG8gJSGIPHZCfH1q4aNGeajFSOAI/leRgGmF6Fg19uOySOZ8Z2SnncjQcb/uWfebQODk0NbKqlsf2HIbun/Wuh2zDyIJeU6BhGgI5ZkHqvH6zTa85ANjHzs5CkgdN8YqeHnpWPfOUPjjZOy8F09PWU9E3zfYQBj2ZpmWj@QYwZatIkO1m01oECiWBuyeC7xywEns6hIFnTt1QtWCUi8tEwKL5nPPJ4REBNnUas02vdbCpwveHrg@hxPe/fqMFlXC9irr6mIZ@oaFhmxdYXUp7YY2JoGih1/zanXTyVDBkugmloeN6sd4LDfNRU@0rSld3@zjCEtUNBIovoIQltMZTzqdegu/8SEqMCnl6TYXZVp8Z1/bS@I7DPBg2T@pmZiWIx0vDa1yEpRLhg2DLpEAu1juvEXPEh4MRUQf6nDkpnE1fsGDDJlse/O7QH/I37nK4qUatAf6WtVYBmc3rTc0E4VhvWuaS@nf1s2HLUUDGoyxjwgpzYCe5p2k6pd3Tz7ixgcb52ecZdK1OByQJ8V0EdtGFUQ0NRzMX9LmJRDx76A2UJlSWD22IbNQq@kticHv8vQjEEnsBQ8PiUrN69LpFpYfEReQCwhwVNG7PUiKFZs0Uc09vjnGQ3v1wKsMISbQB9lMxUqnsOnZ44ZJ3dEvV4vDYS1L4ra35ofnGMF4k8wZWGb4hTOFTx5RnsUXshoqFPszq6z0l14oYFzL3YNJ4YpoDSjM2itHTPSAtX1SHeQ7VR69l5I6dlAEDLndiWkLsk@QEOx8WLaILDiZateH0LA@bdm8RM51dd5zEiVvz6BWZjLbmFWyLpCWvq4Sm@XzBMXxcwV5AaLfgcnzxGJfnI5SjOosKzXAu8LdQyug65yZ/z@/z3sxN1S04ltIjkrCMuZ1L63ovAk68i6d5Vg@EfyAmmm3VaKjLd2sE2xPyhcHr67WAe6HoNb/wz@Zmxjd6c92nG04wIxIdz92yMXhWz/HYMb2XlSVkzPP4e34ziBa7pdsKLR9FzfODiUQNmComZRcQg97rOL1CsZPR4bWQYoZuGzsS8b0tywxZnqbdzPIC@cqxNfFd2FecZdyzm@qOVjJc3OAQMS7ptufxPbGGuTiDQKK4a2l@5g6yRQqpZvjwelEFuEb3Qh8H35@jO1pUukF3NBiTvA7iIwbYKoLBd7kM//PEtrE8ttbteNo1tJs3ZSJSuWc9E3o/el@rUpbLah8YQstmb8/h2r2hOTTnMrij5isTN/gvGcXcPlFZkY1VMTmKE0g4NRpCvRHjz1ulGjt@tC1lMMBsoZHfKB7N5XcDEOwHOEJ/AoYnaLgesGMPB1OVOzUKtJ8uL7nuIGjZTmsqkejzoRypeLMQNiX9eyb9lg7O@GASl8IqG9lsVghFkenuKcuyQdt6GPaVxd9TEZPLJOYJLPacbsQ4P47JzCtUvXXmKTgHejvulFs0o0DAW1sZ27JNf4zvWzLapuP0PqT2gN@2LJT3QIrFJaKbavGaLCU2zbHJtImHky7N9qIJE94XidEsFByO2ZcRQnSS9lY1rKBwAw20M2NdPoUUmfK9KRbo4Wleim@y6C0WVMVkjKYW1c2ljZGLv07T7On8MypsLMO3pa4vxRdKK0KuplUwXDnja2WTtdfYDMsajKGwrBYMirpm3yTrktGE3no19ILPQqCRg7853iqtTC4KN7CAR9j4nlqXi0hRvmPDMM7X3Y6J46Aerp8L10V8OZh/n1u4h329Y/IzZcsY52RqBHdY89HjxDh/kqTE96cZEIxvEllOCtCYzsyxF3znInw0NqA@h/2bZ/lm2r1BW5puauhqZu6yww1iot11unbX7PI9Q6FtUfMAivT5acBlmYD0d7oGI/4U3c8ULdme0@vdpmSRP3Ju6TjtuWnaxzNqLQj6QXjHehM8xOfG2UPo5qmAqL9f1G665hB6K8/xnYGpkG0RaA8nl/h7ERcNloF@3lmrpTMKUCLB9@fFb9wUsKM7/mBAn8agN/ToRUEVOlq4ZMjGp84pSqJL5rgd9Y3Tb6rCUT3g30dQ4QuYTRPPueAWJk7ZZsdpGl3rpkQ3Td23rbNMMMfErUuHvYNIOVlMeYDOas@C4nXHKtJLJep/jJ/DRZUupqt4xxYa5lNBie0NXXeMlB7MRdOUAW3JmpxZnnCV6f0Z4WQxX@5Aw6JUiZXHOd4kQ@DOvWCH2pI1F7FQuZAsSWpHCV0xsyDmaAvnraa2j0ba1Po6fy2SpmbyT4mKrA9/yMSr2FZBU5BWZH4Y3Kdoamqxe24XZ3eHHe86k@TLAi0QzPA1t/Z3O3gK/BaVzysa@jLdFp9FdZDrZXC/PHwbUJtDc@kST37pGg/BaT1Fdyz4NOAD9TpcOGHXswYefzOlnZsrelxftr4ONZ4/9hZ11jLbfBUGTTfJjH3HxVNbIJwohmt6Bk7iI2/nkhjnY7bTAR6v9NgEOICdm4XrK@VzSSLsO5UvHpsdHbd0PrRwd2dvDqUA1tkF85uQfm2oe9bXho5vzsU3u2h@E7pHescyPpkq@QBZUKJi3x//TDUFdLpe@Bddy6MDM4FhycQVEhknW6SzBowc5g35ZhYKwuPly@dmIiKX2G/OlEMW7EsPDbhUgf763LjmrQE4Axp8jsm0bPrf8ml6V3znUtX8jQfLor8Y9gdDT3zmx057g6KT4/0zcvcuLGCVymvg0Kyr9/z5E@iR6V2Q3kRnOjEukue/tHpOh31ZzDIQ9kB4Q/F@DsHdh279ie5Di7DnEDDFvYCXzy7R4syJwrmk9xpowlxnimVb/vJZIt/XYbQVfDEzvAPCY5@Zh/hW730oBuVkfok8XCrJggwwNnqoVoDvu/NY0zWhC@XKDMItcss7MwNo8ZgO/6Mx1D8QpX4RmbkXrFaIfsc2L6Ljv6WLTiXsbB176Ct4vmDpcvqkkyks7WRKbFQsRGiFJb62/@hZMkoytAf3JhHXhDHm0OuNJ6aF2yFmKNGyQcpbzJynoYOBygOTtEQ8pd2iN4TZHeD5NeoDHjjzBlNPxq7p33o0Bj3KsP/ANHAR9Ma4HzuPQL6Dvm0AXLj/1OTH06aYy/yAGOyhY@g9KJ/WjdEcE9o5ncdk3K4PzCbUb29imi@wzUP8QPf1BQIWTUfS4DI03UgrVq9puq9onjFiXjRenk7QJ@aIBi6LCYY3SMU3DC6V44zfVHOZXTHyBo5j8zdx5Sx8tEfLuQ/0F/S6/eK/ipuop7rDueO/6dweheoH@NHJRdl1zabT42/MwoKe0Lb4PgfdtUwv89CyhyNyK2wwBcS5@SMkvps4q26SChhoSMESa7jNGHfNCd45MwwDOflc92gHwvzBz9SW5tvvd@rqruHgqpwwfOCaXORs2g1sPdyzzXdKNKFiRsDUdGMoTjndlNRev9mn18LBS6S2n5pNPPvXpLOpvj6aJ1lOn2ETjjOnyAK2ho2/wBJPYHiUvHnGbHZsN13i1oBexNQv5hJKEN1jyzTe6MlbjasiLYqmrDM6DYHnNqrpbXogA/VMxe/ips@Mv2wuPTgfPGdBZtg3cQ18eiVoISk5XpfowJm/6h@yWtcUO8dx1yI0@sCM/FbZXUioiB7@j@5/moEuuVHYQO0Jw5HSAUZ28z4DSPzQtcXnNsT2xPH8tjU6GqBeLMddxFkwW3kIAh/eCNC0tigTUHv2sMenQzqRbWX9Fg31QDBsO2DqEfP2TcW0zxXSFzW6niPHJZU3mV1UuOabLUVMkOCyhvIwkMtCMPGds5YbZZO4q1XL8IIdFTbEPtd5hXvhhauS4KEMPPpmBt6Tw4dHJ@rA0@a2gmAaE3crDq0erjJSgwvcoGDIdE166@nUOHbJk3QPTZ17yxWzkRmzV7obWa7lO/TwXGLm/rGm7D08VBFgQR3xJRcFPricOPVZvMFj0NWbpq9n9IXDLPQ1/fki5icnjx6mJue0WWKv6zp9Mxn13js@TgOHYp8ez/WOhj6AFtV2RguDH@5rWnIOyT@zaUlzEXOdE9MiTCcmDJahwj7hR4ZvFM8MZ2C2TsYD83Poe5HBe7eMvrAwk4/1c6uDLZdtLSwoatxsSy1sJCPb100X1ZMF30X1eWYNkMMa9Mnwz8LdNCh4rGfc9fnCx7INC7NCEMuKjRQfFkjLXqdW31KgZXS6aMro3i@aME3TFpXzsd6GemX5hZU1DTBPMOk557dY7jbF8EcJnRQfqEqxbtxnv6n0gd1n8IWrB8IRjM2Fu3iWIQidC3Mb/IVpj3Vb4XoElg6@B9ibLgf50rzFelm4QemcbRXnL0aGRw5YwiBj8oaIT9xIkL29@4dLA4jDk6S1LlSHBEycH@sFN8sVelM8NVDBKM5AkyQZTDWAo24YQ5wdh9atMgJMJPRUKpmURKhPQKbqo343DOTRUX5or2WWDYyYyi50lASPmlwSbFVn2xWASCbLXCUSMHzo/IZmmbWtADF0tlbHhgQE8ZN6OuyYuFoSj/Wgmwmw1mps9XJUypa0K9SSUpJZvc7Tiw9Fsj8akG65pzx4bVWvV1bjihJfjZ/aJZaNh@BmzzPng@tTsJBY/IgEh6XL9U46pDQyLMsy1@QF8jGqvevqdguYmOgGIP8u10fFlZ2d4ImPP/@9ltAGSFov@5an96BAUKkn9Ehd52KHxxsU12Cgu6TajfRN9bgqLGVvVyiJ40oAobKeHZwUhSYyoUEULE/48kmYCk43uPMDFQv4nCx4asJD4iLiMFSQKcPpDfs2jMxaftdT2bFFOgOG7uQUoNCravsuLu@20uyQtUzcUU@qIGg3Q89xzkJZ/c9/j@tfI4UQ4qB@ED0pUozEiHofNFJ6ZhjOEFIdIHljuo4ASWAh64Y/xG1DpMeT3JOoJoEUwwGtK4FaNIqG60bb2z1myj6Lo3YfVM5TttqJ1d2nH39ey9Yr71g/Y/7Xb2SSl6Lg5I@AJ3lymgUg5SskrKh3HrwnvnEmr45kHmGoLcMS00EXvD5QuyknMlSYEdCY4wyCZoPzC6SaMaRGoSEpgWaq52ADcp@0FRLBmhekH42OZdsovJKaVQ8aGFiThJq3uspqYsi3syjHPstDhKhjTufaCh3UTmr1TdT1hUFWR@wtIykSujAtnwUbL8geqpfrV0I@uB49AZd5YDaHdBbkPKfm8hXKzmqjsl0lEwxjHNTbWHtxOsplldPR5n494wWFeno6@iib@wJK3XEh1N0Mtrz9xw8uV9Vq9u1bTx8zWb6Kl/mJPWATq5dPDp/sH5/snjw7hlq4ChjbAT@3G/AapCI6it91eqQRE8oF5y4@gP@EtgkTRL3LyaQUPTRNoKKsZUVe5cYIa5oKfUPweeE9M@J/HUDwNOhapbBfACrQidiw1DDzXO8lE2GFKkOiMsun4YOrhgWD5yLn8FIqKplVoLAUKKxbFhVbnNkd7nabErsRy/Ji25kLgiUWxlcL/XkW5xbB1T9Ivge65/3i@eZYluebYJbkG0BD1yDMwe7hw2dP96eDBZ08cd3KVl5oC@DMGVsanwUJdDeSkh4RELcDVWQmUwBuFZ0ZVwlt@hcmZEswR6PPAxOFUvplaUKYUDIV1ExeF1JIIkEpQOkGBZFZZQZtaxRJYtBHR9Bd8iyGTOBADlEHCVdlgTlGGrZVfIJsIFZRXEHTe0JMXPDruBcVf9JBi8OsYR899HibW9BVhb2Ox@A/0isFplydjZjozrQ6U1gOfj3T7kCGA9hkmfdRbJUXhLzK0y6H6UWtyJCm1iud1s1pPkAoAYBeuqcPvEAUjLHHjm@W2OuhQ4qGAmYSyhekkFvnisyparlqblJgBMNmEHyDfovwHR4cV1A646IZ8fcozQ1t7KgAiOsTF6pAfBd173MdDVyxLy9yR6icDbpKmmb2hIrJUErw2LnlWTCGpkpoo4zTA06JuREZR730pGKK7fY8kEla0H2DhOJjVwvCiUonx/nxccVmcgxoUg1FxjSTJYT1KtdVkEJXeoGD@pc88CrBEWYvgjO@vaIoUHIdyw6U0JdQKz3NsJaY7w5xp3c1fi1IkIQSmZSu3@9FAOdoVz41M@9//Ydco/KpD@bvCPMoex9svypsbTD/WuCjaWD7Z6EtB7bvctuLDFbZda2zk3RO1BcvPGwP1HlPlmKzWUPWECjkpyyFlY4V/vnhE@YZqIQZq7SvjyK1hYwmGKkwqw@0cU5VjeA8hklNTvAkap8DpQB5AZmglIOCDcVnuvUEqiAtZTKYclxQV2nTvTnie91II@nrIarWBlksU8gXNrQMJFI5DxCSnrAOHhzmCJPJErBG6dwaVF42Dba9vc1kz9B7ZqVQ5iSSWdVfrMsvw4SuAqzExws1BmEgyCQE@FVFsMSqntKSGBT7s7gWR9bWcjjFgVCYIAOAJNHZDjQLgdTpiKICcrbNkU@C0zgYBwHftp2I0usAkQKIOG6uLnq6VU4OA@OCT6SdqtFqkJ8j2DGCleR5NFt7wU79U7suFIEzoL8fzaFgG8z/ZI52cE6HqDntuhbrxKwOaswNu3dsO7h2dgCpZYlcJree0QrJSOOTBSpIL7b4t4AS2jjwDMO0XjkDb3dv//DToyfH1xT6EWR8FizO4tXt1Kmipmv10BAP0z1dqPcPMseP7h8ERRlN1WTWByEmJx1mkzkvttmULoj9OT93fT1u8rgWkZa9LWLaRqwc0GGh69gnvpkI4B4/9nkt1kTy8qpW366e2rFr0b@dp3I@pq4hcYHp1COF8/HZZGISwytmTvCKGU8N1IloqEsEj5r7ztlEM4lwiHhw8AALcABJzQRQi9gnJOCIzwBNVGjl@B03HrE@PktEesPDFEUgT4LbcLBpTTS@ClWnXd3r9qymBF14C3Ufc0VlgSauUMWZ6g16lp9ISkI7LggTqJlW3IkzKo1U2oWTSGIzJ1xptkx7aoAvKUEjAHzxJ0Ovy544g8jc1gMzMD0FeYQ9GPIdGSb7dNgHuDZ9npo0JQ0SigKBoaDiYVL5uBpallCeOkqhglqIr4YqVEXG1X4rnxgl1a45alkdYOCJZBpa@kcaCFahehfMNClUtePA43gJf4wnZ6NF@kE6dEcT5HpNVy27ZY4SqBSuVAcJFd3jF8/P48BSZ2mAFPnuBao/ZzT6Bg1R90WLmGjDnWlsW@FFODOakbe2ULFeHzd4VxjEeOy7D8EI/VOi3dcHLDEkPdseUxlZE6cJO@35bpIpVa6tymapFI2r4UMeIDcjaJtMRDgsgfOQiUwFagddPbuFnzfWgNU0Va2DmSJJslWcU9uDrhxno5ISjJMgSInQVrBuWQlTxKlX5ZQHYdBfIt2XDJVNz/EmDcm02uJgWVCuWfVuRGfgpAXyUt3aKonamGY1WwzI4jqXVzOAdg4LCeRUKF@hfgRKDe9DwYtzcOEX2MK9z0zbNqGAgGb6OvTB@hCIzE2mg0uw0pP7M7iIxZP4idBnAgmdvldjP37Zw31Bq5kyTc@Ur6BPfXmKnWpbdKvjzH@fUTPly8RqrzLOgKCTrCZWuxUttb6WSq3aa4lVG7v6u3dxVudqFSSJhgqDpBEAKau9ZBnoGSSPyqpdXtW3E6utSm6NQoAVhmmXEOCdl1EvV/WrzOpd6KnT4OLyxptY9UiZcVZVtStIH7aQ1UwaaOYSdb/SDVgY/aqVSmEa1NUGJuBd5vQ4RTz79DhDE0hlIY9mOn3R3Ga4algT1@7/4gUonEVFA2PPIWMXx8IaATCqhwr2BMzxWyB78Ig/w6UiRqvSphcdAMjTPrdnLILfxUnPJFcdzbVJQwGOElCIaE3rySQwk5/9LKYVmJxY3Sms985T8Xy2DC@tnGd59tHqqaLkVmsxFru3Wtd1vwFD98za5emDYuecme1c4XXNaquvi5Un6bP6kydfvGu8ezEaJ08T8dje0VtZ2wD4TbZFv9s@myy34LmlJsbYWkaKZda0u5uZzMuXL0HoxadWVasBiFp/9y5Zi9drm5inRYjiiVwueWxZVoadDrxWC35lp8voTrp6jD@pVEIhF3gpNe62s9MftdEw2jU7neG@PubuVmyInwNfhH305fPnz9HwnB725il3ZzGOkQm4UkPPx1gum/vzn6xcpS@fNLb//Jv9jLmCnyP8fOfqEZqPtfxHKysf3b@/sZGG0uLmJ18@@fru7u7Gg3T@SS2/s6FkV7b/7E9XVnK57Vxmpe55Wj1eO/tCzmU3ZPXPfxxvPHnyNc/DCsNnnWlgxHcRfhrL59kZewPPWZvhP5nftCJmHc3N9hsWexPTNC02pr8GrjTg0LpCzGf6WWFadWfzv33v6HXMj1VzmecufP3Y61ihGONGMIBtPbCdx6qxbQQrXMXGmUqlAsbN//ZvIXz1U8CDPuNteFXzAa7COFZVKhTkbaxaAIOWy0G8//c3vjGdlns1eOSNzZy8U4dnjZ5tKVYdgWe1enjActXcmiAkrXhXuxsJbPtdEEVOY1px4@geWS3Toa@NX92GQSu0H03LnXJC5XTDvzinEps4d6H0oNaZE5sGJbNwAfjnMaIgICGiIm4WDkRY3OH5LNzzU11f20xt5O7Z5efiCQ2/vOcpXqpYWLn38kEms10FaQCfUuneadAIM2yzKDvOPZwiZCMs9DJ7GBZwVc4Wc3I6nb6H8CMFn1FsUoKMFxKLTRVtjE1sLOoUY0EwNoH5ULh9fP7i3//F9//ie/T3ffr9JykW7OxTauf1avAADclVV748FdbR1ANMqv6UadmP38bz6/FjMEET0kLfSY5isWoVX/QvbGSi74yb8KmGFoKYBJkPxwQjCgo1JsXeZTIMq4SdB9m5t1JaKZYKpVymwWZycg@qSc5tbsn1ai6fO4Kq02SquK0IFGDfgWcF/ugfntCK7xVyEc4Ecv1ZYdVbP7MsXorVYrV6nTfuarSWbnqeqkoZqE8lSyOa89i5FFOAqaVST4G4mSByeE5TNz7PUqraEGY0OPB1FMUBrFLsl/BUJRa7hKf@bq32bi2IuVYVhm2lXk2JBMFHbdyrp5Srq5r6IlUui3@QHMuhDR/4MPhBRupXirL9ApDVptHGN5x4wbmH2DlyequNF9uAPrVd2644e/RTG1i6Sv1FtbY9jUIk7t69lAq1cA8QVFfrLAliqaKs1BbmARDWEwyGNlDHV9tX1ava9tXV9jb8b9P7SnzB9Wr72j99Js8CmIl/HanqtJapnmZEe6/Wwa5mquiiZk7BUIUvwEGvI8UukSBZra7gUKui1LRCvk7SBXvEHvHHtuEffoEVXdDhEbrZ/GVziAAmdOYuUmwN2GympK3l1jP50UeF/RzwKg@jzslyZg0Nb7HvB5FtS4rhOGiLD4e2yOHl@6/@d/ydvv/qD8AK@cS7acm3@Rr/Hr7Bv9c@/p0Y@Pf0Nf6xkzf499THv0dN/Hvi4d/Ja/zbbeLfSR//7r/Gv0c@/j3r4J8UqzAGMurqTraXPc9qZ9oZGCyWhSFCN9vVWsAnWdZk2XF2zLJ9R2uByYS/LJisbJtlOyxrZ21NA08w@Czro6kNnw78tQGLC39WNovIs@cMYukh9yXt/fR922DJU6nG4i9NECtVTc2qBatRR01gIEuWY5nT0wyXtlluo0xaxK6uWKOx//hBo5HB9nv6yDma/B8d9aPWpf/9I@fRkdN34P/o6OjRKXDiaupeSrkHT6Wa2hafnVi1vHNaUpDeg6YVy2zvnFbXFTQXUtBacuiW@sBnghG@1ZVTKX4B/flFmcSG8sV5@aJMhtDKDQ0BIMC4AUKVhbgBLhDu9HmGxIMLeM4JL9nQeAGegYkbMs8vTlFchgFS@A/FEbX@A/xb/9/6f/SMJWr1JLSBy6vtBD1J/EsmL68ur8S7mkwkhCWxDX/oAHYMcnlVRSMBXYKplkjWk1dX3A3eieQ2R1jFOLarFHgCCJwpFsZJ8fJX4h/2i3GL5zReBom5spoQS5@np6NsNllugku4@qG/pVW0ZJn2F602a1r9z36MsyjaTpKA8hvlsrbGzbmNXLm8ISybxXK5KMyricTW9aea3dEKINhsbCST5TJYdgKcWbAGOIuAU5jzgNL0dKOM7b4cS2L6OTNIZHFKlq5uissl@e7dhLjpbGcwSN69q21l374NnRqNluU2Gui@/vat3JBxd1JlKw/2bPHtW@BD8aTjJh47fF08oWjso1yVYthyXMjlJngzLZObxNnVPd333cQba5CWcce8JyfpuoVs1nFP4z/97je/eRqv4H4Vct3QEAHGwvLb24WNarWwAeZCEQpCXuUboBKd1JaWvFrNyDy7TF6Nx4SXVtxMkutVHP1ZbJvtVKHxeviwy6sYVSnbyCcTzbGZvASXwE3b2uKObKOQKKa2xF9lJcmqa0z84QhtPbWxtrl2D4doo/kPstvypV6JZzLxq8qlXsIJvKuyIS73wcOt@t2761tQpMVs@VRqNB7snuw28JZj3KAA/TBDR@LdEi4@D9x4jWZb81v1GmavfhqPl8r3qPK1Yp7F4mUBp8ShG2DFLd4HxDxPstp4zH1EaGd@a7EB0zbXoVeGTlka0GaxzSxr4Xq7y5x2ewUcoQpZE7dGeGavF9yIdOG4vdaF1TJXpNiTh7t7@yfp3DbIC7mD3b107vjZ/ZiG1vzETt7raH@6v/vg6BkEePJwf/d4/@PDz/efPQF3T3rlvtFNUzeHptm4GA4vXrNXltWwoPR6Q8uyHMOFRDRM0xwAWPCUTZOZhuXpr17p7oAexhn5@x99@/2P/of3v/Pd97/z7fe/8/2ffvX9b8Pv9@D3Xf797r/ZyuP7p1/9s999/9u/A47/CX5/DL@f/PSr3/wG/5H9T@D3XyJufyJ@ETj@kwDXr/70q@/9@Kdf/doP4Pcvxe8H13@//pP5v@9/a/EPw33vd5fDfPffwu/3Oa4A9ru/zd3wew3@tzncr/3g/W/8O/7/Z@IPjb/z/jf@BF/C8k9/8Gf/5f03/0MuV/yzf/3@2999/63vvf/WN99/6zvvv/WPc@9/819r2ejrd99//w//@o9@/6//6H@h/9@j9@/f5v/9D/7pX/4ff/kf//KPxO8n8Pt3YPrJX/4HIN2/@8Mf4f/3/vDv/vhH@P@//au/@8N/8Xe/@r@S4Yfc8P/8y3/D33/z6//5b3/rO3/9k2/87b/4yd/@8A//@v/8tf/rN//z3/yPf/A3//M30fGHP/nrP/7Vv/rmt//qW//8r7751YL3t5e@v7qF@1e/BJfbp/M2eG6Trw91@ernSs8vUhqTWIBO6EojlgOR@P7YZGUpy7KMv6Cdfv@fvP/NXwHy/w0ABNv/BDb45xbw@g5Z2BdfIG@M@rMUTf4oqS@@QH8xnP8CbLEqzdlhL1HMFVNrICWvbW2Fk3nbEzTfgRBvMyDbZ@@9BRRfUHj@sC8CMEjbbxEYwDEBFsBNJ5JgcJcsd//pV//8x@QRhkXnX5lCmQ2co9CrCP42KI7vIG@YZDcK/R1kL@9/9I33P/7H73/0w/c/@lXsT5SNrfRuGqSC5XPkAJi/BRwCFm4DB4AajnnZCluRcmBY2caZXUlLvXwJqV8BEwzg1qT8OtgkrUpmDc0QMAU2xif8UviGf2lji6EFXEbkCl@WAq/7KVapVFLSqILTgwgKVgwzYtUizkHhfEsF8GIgHibdKMLYiI3uExYIWUk9ZY21yogHTKFDlTAgXUno9FTWcnKqWHkAEVZGDxjiQuQp6SV8X1aqxcqoiujeURIAR@o@RAlQFUzdqPoO7BXCCfDS6ME7SEqxkkpVi@BSwUymKLZ0g@LU8pQ5ynuKpcTUJ3xxt@rOPcY@krWizCdJoSiZgMZ3agKNgAAO/qepNZEd@g@M9FvD8FBPIyof7sb9d9CZwgsAwKsouMkRfoqCqbkH3iOOKkXRwifFMUDJpfgMGAsdSMhJSSmq3xRZIH5Iwwc/gHK7KvEMra6uSmiV1@XGEQxKYfTnnpU8X3dxEZak0BKTC1syOuOOsSCDuLVw9QmNYdcerMFbg//9FdoHTnkqr0mrcZx9iTMR60cp/rt3b419BGVA34mbxJTUurPhxHh2t1MpOQcRVx2wrVFWU4QI5y/oPyW9iEksRjQAjSbN3/BRK@TOYHgv0ksOLyoSpiy3rqEdZ2OHwyGGUNW0mk6Lr0pfclCFQSVf8VVXSdrk52V7eEYkmKfYkvgIi2mFDTogRJdMJllSihkminFMeuR17jsjGMakZTmtFXAlLymmjE5KOWzF0n4pC@@vO6VS5Z22sSnBl@xDvOxSHD8FeuqarqlubyNdVC8VmiRDI8i/BalaFfsZmCZVj/dPAPzkiGm5rMpgCHS5sZnbyG/kc@uFQn4zp20UtjYK@eI6cNxCNp/LaVsbG1vFrc2r6dUcmoMuFuRGShvnYCQiFzZxEvofXXv@u38075nvio9U/YKNVFyeUK6kaq/Ct9qu4mYH@TQrl2kGjwp2tZZN419ufR3ekPC0lt@sr6z0LhUsh1Pa33mJ20kg7dKlwmDceAceJt2R2B1wggfiwOVeJjboHB6VxWYMvMGbb8iQtTzQO1TMKRA8RycNok95yjYAeri8vIz8pNjKl1/6rFqFIY9yeCDFoCV3WbA3QbFaalele6ZbQ9ck3w5jLetzCy/TUVuWN@jpY6DTrCrFrq6u2uFqGVl5iBa@rwxyaYL5aqRL///zy3tyOSW3rqxriraO/zcYcvh/e/gc/OfwDaHWc9I21ydVxftmHb1VCe9kZ4nkZavScgw6PlZuV2p1FU/il1tq02mNVc8fw4BcEFAl3uw5xlk88LTwojo8BlvJ6Bm10QAK9B0YpdO4fie3mS@tZNyMilvrE22W3MkVNsHl1A6cwCWPLi@mnbZKLTVI0SNoKxAuV8oV8lfbQt1kFfKD6apiKi5F4kq2Y5tXuJ26pLeBk14afBNSSc7li3K5Vp7YNwtyuX51r2@2LJ2dZvH03uXcgIWCfBXAQdQ4xsdZGJbo4@VSuE@/lD3NJhcEzkJgSDKlVNoWOqyqtK2kBiyxjlfs1urbgXarqvTu3bsR7eQqHdq@2NKV2yiiO5NwUuEuCF53NW7MFybGLBpPUBPZY6g7YOQ2e4hnM3yHnTj8DMB901gAsdfV6cbhPdfxvF8A5r5un3GvBxbXgBR6faLjxQpe3/K7CyCeDfp43NZ0f2kY9vtNSCDSFAe4Dy@35zjzADbZsycLcvko1GCIu79IhSGAPz38@JOTyPdkf3fvE6nA7h89fjDzyQugPHu4f3ASWje5bxA0H6L4@v7Dh7NW8QGpoUzTXyssv4m7vwOLxnRfvyjHimVZrrFRHUrGvwIxu9yyh1va3bvaExePWBTYRrWYLZVOs@UryFLl/llpgPvIPXOw5u2PtjYgi2zInkGh664hy9AKD3b3sNGlMpV4C5fcYezDVv/mt37PXLPXZLnMcLeSXACxBPedb2n8GKXlSXSWGa@1xSusfQm1JLWcC5tOiDZ7Q5MNB2yhI3zQCY2u1en6zL9wAgCpqesMfh/6QHgz@vjLHXweB7ld8@nNAcdtTlabZSWVRLncVjFf3FrPFdPFreJGXivk82ktl9Y2i5tbIHhktaJWKOa3tHRxY2t9A8Ql8M1vbUoxEBisdiYDMqomy/AtAVrbwKvZtvGOO0ftVqUYn59mbxJ6ksX00D5ksglhZLwT2PPpcM2aVZFzG3jyDWRWwKgzg8UODvayBweyfB8tuKK2l5XlFlryxWx2874sm@SzByJdTpYdHqaIShxkn1uy2ft7sjzkCFDHoix30bJfwIG0LFto2ds9OMB42mjJYXgAO@M@3NILLJsAZqNlfZ1G4rL8OkQHcLs8og1K6T5aME70OeA@e@Anyx8H6clmAcNTDscxfBLkdXdXlg@5ZXcXffYo43me1M/QskuPLLtgASKU5Q4YOtgdyHITjEiKsmyAyRjr4IbX4KGaPdvXZXnMCwiLSJZHBK0bZzKMF4U7RvPJJ5/oXb9ldvgzdvkX2twh@Fij4f5B8@OPm51O0x3v7n/8FH329j7R2@Oh2@w0RbBmAx4HwoDPWX88@0AaDxsNvTfX5zPwsWd8GuOGiWlr6K8hTeLpYCT9xh747IHPvOl9jg2ePoA28bnfh@99vUk@wUM@9B01m3IZCRX1XOBkPLaZMxt4QbqvG65TRvuossLiiXh6XCtk62VyZ/0ES14C90L/doJuVscxFojal@PaqJKtV0aVzZw4oZeQT0e5vCWnV/o72hYIJ/qOlttIjUp4E4fTjrO4ou0ktLtrbxKPQQ5Z3yjJpzs7ilzT6js5rVgqbL5YG8pysoTvnfXN0hsYdsVhbIWvZG2zvgMSzyTI5mZKz@RKm5s4JCtfQYn40CM1h77ZaCQSF6Z@lkxiirGfBymMssvGlFWr3E6M0qMKTxgbQ/hRRStzvU8sew1ZC1UODvEWY46yk8ASGO1kS7gokpC1raIMSchkEskkMiZkJfB9@TxYzQ0/EcOUkT8qKyn8EnStWEiqeOCr4bQbdBEsexmFnGy0kJ7jKU3S0BBspabJAK8kneCQE3sEkq6sJnAZrm9jJI24ZjHG5ye1zS1JqooB1hN@M2VZWD/@ZE@FMZewoRJD9QClW8dV95DtTflwBXuB0wl0duonJm6QNgK3Pa47Qd0fwQgbReTAI1BGpQp1QOrJJ@VLpYELKV87OTs5@UK5iqI9hsEmTwieMCuTLhHU1oAqH60W0ytVMOkoS1IqoQiSF1QcjWq10qj0zf7AH0Oeg3CfMdKIOEF06PHMhCffKPglngcVHo1K9moC/3jYZ/c5EB0aDYI1KvehfLNlGzUom2hdZaPYSKq2UB/k/cr9y2EJ5dGrslkxXddx5RietN2xK0Pb09vmE9PFQ56HR6uszUw8Tml0X57uI@QeCtZXStVl9lQ6ErpSbSannSJWLLrE18ISuaRDCrj2dwXjk8SLZPk12NxVlmip95M7G@VW4j5rJMEl@7L9ss1yrLBRpkuHEogJOAKVHJaInqxUPwPEHO9ZqQQJESRxBjgxolWoEatFPnpyYF2VO5UaQr/F17Yiy3VFqb2tS9WyVAUGUx7H9Io3bPLbxLNNLZctlEfgpm1ulLusWWm@GJXdygCG5azcg2oXcxH85IWOu/ChkADPm7eJ97/yDZbcVvIV7lgmZG97IEw01EZlNKmh9Uott1FI5wobOHVRWIefls6t53BjcTqX3UrnNJApQNaA8PDbBPsG/AAGRI6chhMciV5CZkxOZ0dZVUtrppZOZF9arZfJ9BnOM4FQSIWWTPvOvg2UAw5IQEC2ZIWvnkzl1nqJlsP0bYVoGJhemTKqp7tsYKW7iOapqfc4eFJh62uJ3moCYVZPhoP9Wr1U2h8NvoZeCeX1TiG1mU29SSbLiRWWrHjmaypl5I9UCoMVoGgxb8O8Yb@WXYF8QxtUrqC2/VVtM1eqDVdrigYZzL7tbMtVuQ7VdcUk@IsuLoPYVQa3gA9yQW0iak3cBihf90yoWm0rVxYg0kAw5oScOJWDg0KJeHwzF48n42Wc1FwBd8HYiQXHoVeI39V2ZBD15JK8lZOBp0/4@bUk8Gm/gibFriQc4LKNLSl2KV1dXm1H90l@xsZjHURw8dxlrJNalViGNgSpjRhbIZOiVmn2ebey23m6WxbQu3tSrIS7eic7Ltkp19KgZFYieyNv@2xXX/DvKe7vg1gl0hlWY3XaQGBapG35czz4tsPikC3d7ddyufV6LbcJXTrw4QA0l9PKq6kMi6m0jROqw7uUeOHTprbMdqqaOZVkmZgR39pQzNO0KOToXYyaP9u7DOY5SngBRkIv8cZeqyffPbZ6l8V1hQ/HgftcXbEY31@eu7a/HCIO9gt/9jKXh3qyncABBuA@8HvoY/N5GRKQeTnwvswV1x8dHtkP3AMzmObcaMjVGMtqCm7HLQvHfEMux9iZEtdKtPt2cLz1YvNF8cWjZ0fPjg6k2OnK2xUHRnP3VrLZUrFUZOXyO/vTr7FBfH0jDtV0WomNKhviEIlWrSrado7tAHkzKIVDu60VlOzbKifWKvkUcuD1/ld@sDHaLoI9B6J1CUo7n8pVq9paLhkbvP/qD/AU8eX@57sPWRy1uvz9n/44t/n3f/qvaN9I/Krs0VTiZgwg0agVNmOXl4PLyyt4uF8@Vo/xRG1sJsHM9@NosWpGOGubWjLmKTExu72Zj3lvhVcui0cQwHfviDvIhTw0ltj@Uyuf0@5tYxVpYRWx8G/b9LZiUqz46OVbxsBiVFudjpUjUybDSu8Utv1O2WbvcGr7nbLCXlaquIKmZTK0wZjPrK5Vq1VEw@LVVGYtznJ58KtdlespRjOzMLZ7gWPd06mp7FMbnExvDf9M9Cb7mueBNbCZa688SCTLVzUGo8NM5jT5/ld@M5cr/P2f/vrbxtvGF8C8t7a2Clou9jNI0pIzrMHwjiaI8DQqGsJhIVtwobJqyFIMb9luMw4fDBJxWIg6HLgGLLRJ544l1Bw1oPh0kMkTBLaGJ/HSJJ3Tsf1kWZJCEZakb7djpAkHW0Md8tDSpEvpDnpBx8cqwOukOxNU4NBH1VlGw@sN3QEJkgkKp9XT7C4EgRjuoLKVFTpBKBimopVZZu16UJ5krneJRBXWNz0Pta0BQ5fuQJCHQMJ0ox0b6HgKFSEtGzi0iiCUTvJo1SDuOsTd4wEa5Jqg3HOANOOp44FskM6lO3ikjsR36M@ZtQ0AZZaU7kABQB4SArFVZ9tsPckurVSqPFHPdoXbJFE3hx6ccZMwGGJr4cHOIHAZ4SyugmXooloyJmrYMKOOARKOgy@/VWBggcHJhvIQHWO9NSrAReoMEpQ1dvfuJFWVitVKMsoR4kfddKhSbqJL61oEgCwYlX3UKslpZqdSWNl3pskOSjxFyQWqU8gwAWrjYUO0XkkS/N@aaJEiZ6qKPMqYAVFfvFUYUGQQGIud16GB2vW03GaShYk3IO0GJYrU9IRDzdPRRyppyzJ4Eq@kn8UCfcvAX06iAyJBt7OHHBl0YkPUhIsaHDgzEMcX@cVdyKcO/SB0GAqyYvUIum25MLSgRcNA4U9iXUtisHboQumgrZC5DYa7FPNJ/FAohEa1MDqqWBHxrNAcOOmm8waOTTpZ6HQ7bu4kTXmexDXQ8GQP7QudtKvxWGjrYyRFXGUdUj5pVLO52jiPh8UFSn5TgyibNDM7Kikfym2xBFeCiFOWdoguSYEowTCg1LGMmz2zD0k6Nk2GWkG8UibTAVlk2CQ1II8soKvugQW9he1lxFWCmQvrzMqcoBZXxWmDfCuOncZQfLFCnVxC1wap1OtZZyYf5yamzg17LFdIg/yYhpKd/KBgSziBi2eDs@Cd5lDw24TPJjcW05GwK4lx8vp3XVtJNLBG33LtVi5eF3iu25HypeetJEan3tgLlALQKVWwqyHLhZbJTwLG8ShgeGRVEtoLKnSyXsWZ9UECRK/gLCsaQWQ1zwFC0STsY4BpGsEhW2zFkNs71AFQ24OWhXpzfLeEp88rqFEuYUDTEwzeZh@x9ZxE@gVJH4NQnwA4sOor09jBD4JiPjy/BRWj8ikK4CvQOvst8IuhGilOfhg@oG40kw6pCXmzFYEOOx2Kq8J4swgs@YgFWwfXCAhZXwHPAqRwTkpWEnIK0KbkpMxRh@Fng3Nql4iXlNh1TGmGGERRAxYUFe7rHtdRKlTeXFxcqKR3aehaqumhdm8Pr0HNDDoWyKxOxjf7A3FHk4VX9YlrSCcmhev0xwtzd0Z0T@3W3TH/SlIbz4G/HlqumYi3vTj2geeoiLrTJ5UWqGzCI7o5sEjHvZGglWlPkFmunr4MyKyEZKYU41eIhDFEM0qP00YakKWbxlm6fdEqCw9@wzsgh8oyA0dUiegGlr4XmKxBO4RwfNpVHdibvTPD6Tkoesh8JnYSNc9hADkOrMI@sEYQyDYv2K7r6uME@ScRGuk0MSbpho2hdycfMEJvwi655jBrVBvXp4KPwuDQd4XrsS4qtJAulyPlCtvQf8T9R@A/4v6jSaRBtLVRnUte6HSF2UHiRg1VASSiGQcwV1zf3MSHMIOEzDSOAiHHU25X8DMqFDoob26DeqwEhAE0QWoeE6hfsnZatz3zYq2eynSApmUqCKhxQF2rU5letEIzln7vvDdwvCknG9U3Qecj0o1ORldQA6cVzGNYQUQYvLws1PLT6at8Mob3@yLDgAHFLfBECWDXT1jJcqhflzyBcGrypIx5wmoiMXUSsoSXcAOpiBc9L9goonoEEbqHWYJkgg8LWo64sUEwgecuXpsdwCp0AwMpCo7X41CSM02Fs5QyVVIkVYoSJBOKHaXSymxWAn@oitqMVySbV6L@o8lf@eDkt6FdzE89ESzvF8pStKmYI1SLaormQqXKqpVIvUIKMmt6z3Shg9rnYqjolCGatUwwmuDxYBa4Ot9EpPKNJK8fOsMi23IpJIVxpQJZHFd4s@TtIihSXuBhME8EGweEIMJzBgI4snODmSLYKBpsVKlwxsFGC4JdRBI5okSOeBAOPVqQyLoIBoOkUGEsVk8d9QSCQCUDPo33lqgTV2aefo6Kj9kr1OoDg6cgzgnPISoQNISSNNKZUZ8bey2S6AjTmkGAhHgNQYtfElWSZhmepoS2kEfxogx4FLcJMuC8AgiMWHCZa25LhERGQ12Q6@UU9QPQduVUTZI13DZGf1n@k9OBY/DTrjtmpyG1acdseubvl@JYx5KNNNCIkKFlN5Ah44BllxTZgFhy4bDEHOEZ3DPBBeOZZs9pZvo6bsLIuJFrx5PBeICUVd4bOL7uOxsbJT4Isoi@nglwFrmmhY8BrI7twFAjqhvS4ros7Tiq7DScjm15ZhovOuciuEnbBbjSdikq9wqj40mSmCHkw1JEzQkIRddGA6@2azQSntlrJ0uh4lW0qkiH8biE41kwRcIDHxJIjwYJp/nKNPzkzThRcaoIdmIZZ4mjgfCMQyS7DJiVAfI8@HZBVGGeMxkJkj5DFI2bfoJU1nedvtMB8Q61lWLoGfSHE9yYIH0woLSkmY5D1FJEvSw1h4SR1pMi6GcfHJR9lkvoyTB8bhrBVGGkmTtbxliy7pzoGguj48GC@I4/PL3H0fQeL08vjapn08yH2hXu@WFRrycmGABwkoz1m5ORFsrBryVnKimhMwpQPMCtk9iiTU4tTOkugO4KcLUN9JEObR4pLBIJ/3xR@S@vwCD4/m2rT8ebPo/HwG/6uJcuQZc2eME6YgLAD5PIe65HF5L2g1vGBbB4jcoBygogrxLjslEbFjTMAQyjPTlcQxGIb6B53Md0je5pc1OFe85Jk3ueZme5xVX0oNEye/rYbCUEZDqCN8jxUxiZEb@6XcaR0RHTc/igLgGdVDKqTBsLnQOVFpCMnj6PqFK/BsNBrJB6aOabUni4uPzQ/xprxim7Cp99BoE/Ho@R1n26JGEwHoy5FtEeqSMO@Cjvf3hN4rHdmwsEykFsgUhPok0uY59PE2GWbtEjhLDqdJZJX1jQbTn9wfU6/LAiujmnULmRQJWglqc0nS@qcWtZjUeoIqBJvtRzO5K8iehuTXMRUuPIJixs78O6kGuYceuDYSSiGLnL0hpz7Gs8Ad1o3s1e0Ks05jDUMCRxOt@icTXJF0kJh8CH8MUJpM/hiwg7pt/gBBXkDeeoxCU4jHz6@iAitQgXkMYBS6QUg/ssKBkRKCkwA/jlVRinsTBO41qcxlScYQuYjjICJBlTUYpawOpZVgU9s@0v4M7ohYNk@Cxj2/DYju7itMRl3IqXrDSLn8dLwJDjZry0nwCmHG/FSw/I4MVLx2Q4i5c@A8OkbcXfxktBs0AAF6xkuIfugoWj3YiX9hLJK8nHK0eCeNV4KaxTgNnhVioRKArMN0iNuGRmOyKbvmtCx0ZCZZohxXhpHCfRhEuafln453cL8DtwwBPnLNcImKWYNtVpRHoMHg90G4HO2TktuSR68/2jA9o6NLm8AfxTMJiLhiH0IIbH4tPMiCcMfWmFAr6QQOSbpfkpYtr0DR@3SI6IHSiUKnk6fio9leSBVoL8awBcT05fHCHCB/U1jYJX4O3SiYEXpfNacoLoKEW4xpqckyws1JfxJZnCup65FYXXfrSGaO56Gggvwg1AeC0R2ghPBxmOFtswsoEzmCYS8sUNgVY0DM2@8UaJ1DsTjLiCaJkLvMlZ5AwZQ7TxJ5dlJxIOkzbFgtCzlq3zVhb2C8SL0WvC6yKSKm98kIQIz4EWbhpnJpLtA2EkOM5u0tRXLOqGgrA8SuJc02wSAquof2So@zz2cPC6j1pJPmz4GoQc4aRKAhFEQoaxcP7qfID87nD5PRCog0KYiWCeYD2/K70uXi/tZWdS3ptEe70C0TPNHiTnCkdhDJMih9FBRDJfRmvXRHzcwsGFfB5piH1G2g@KLRwT3FBus2MLjgulBPd82vEsB45nucUFdV0i6Z2rgdCiYkwCD894mNJJ1panlWd8XhWjD01k670PrmB3uoKjlYf4KAPuTJHzVo4HPXFta9K2SaEvuiBL1UqMM3Ja/gyreeII7J6WYsNlWHA4ajx9cPT44deh093c3EyKPno8SR@2WpxUDftxjpm2LYf9wZxhSy6NCu1x8ZoubsZLpVdObfkaL@HMGoQBvMonID/RxpOCl0X4@UzbhXAcNlKiAtfZpBnoU1wJRR0du2xLlKsPBWL6iTVdIAnEWyjvNI3WkjgnC9SBtwI2GtR9NRq4GanREL0YVk2wwp38WWwlM/Rcup@Xq9u@kCQ6t80eHLHnn@yesJNP9tnBs73P2NePnrHnu49P8Jzzk2f3Hx7uMfjtPz7eZ5MZBXzwChIcUEK5PjANs9/Ee3yz2Q1GmPecwZjzncRekrsf6332iWOYuB617en9e11uUW3Tr/JQ@zAcHeMcpkX33PQt3@cX@BmAjoSbFh1vw/3/DGCbMKbt45i377SstgWwEo59B5bpBSewWM@CGgR@G5ysTHMhCa9Doa1AdBke3WOIF@EBPC7SABrdm1y8aHk8gNlSmSi48PngEjzZf/romO0@fsD2jh4/ODw5PHp8zA6OnoL1ydcPH38M5Xl4fPL08P4z9CLAR0cPDg8O93bJgScgqzI8yU43Gy5LgorgVCrGGS5x0z3doS066wxgIMGzC50O@nksPrSR@1h6z3pjtuJlCa9K4ocLaU2AhRcVMvM1LmUGa760n0B@5tFlP6tZtk2xQWOpQnsri@YK3R4qXceFh/6Y4aVPZpnOkyfIPLlMijbltCyTyXu45wTnvvmxc2rLAWqIaAVwI6pgA0qF0Q0G8Xh6m1BWITaj56BSNh4b3xQoLBj0XrB1pCxRiYm9L4gUDwUc2jgfpJVDB6B7cMiJaH2XA7D10IEDsA3ugKLoIe4FYXkBMfSPhsieWYE7vOoPDmj9l22GDvd1GsUWRZp4vVGV6iy8RQUP4ffoDgo@y0OXS@meYVkUxCN4vMOh1wtueGyaQPLAE8V9XLhXDSBlYDZtXGoQ29jsITVs8AVqwH0/etv3WKKSVNkJbvYxbYtf7tHp6Tbf0jTZikO0x4qofaQidm9b4a0ZdMxi4BAB4k020@kIwz0QUqF523AQ8v61GHWx55FuXgq2lN2UgPvXEvDzoAFEytRIx6Ceis56IhqnLUg54TlAkThv@y4KD@TcGhrmVIDg/s1X1ps3SVHI6alxUrDvkFIHVYRXlab5mmXbcaGNE1vt46EV5IJG1xn4Fq/DxHQOJrenATR2bBDby0p1Kja6MXUmRtuxI5E2gYoXxNoEorxNrETxfJE8ZF9BWw@vb6N9dJgcvYl3Tk/WztK4iHRh4vQLCML86knsbegiYSF/ShPe8Y6uAy1Wqg/unyrvXqbx6gnOFviFa8EmQn59aB/jguZB63y0AdFFuUu0tOD@Em/YxNBiT53gltjKA2QwDuxaMK671yiHfnz78HV3PI0y606Ob99WeCgFORPnyEOvm5hwtzSrBVGmKUydib0eEd4JiQVenwhc0oQz5Nf38OAJ1kIZSsRGPkIX/07fGyJYSJC75rANnEXcDCaqO8SfZFXaOhEIkvQkovWReZG4X0lVk5nJzhEWKc5EwKLTAWa8OGyy/4T6q2voHixHB/z79uiKS1PHu4cPwvZgKbYPSpuSWoyLd0sRXLdH@24JWt65/VxoIe/pxYh5J3kdW0jpIXGmV2Ph7tjlMb68VnfU9gAN9r04gxIijcQ2tGmJOlCTmuABklE0E4Ho@OTB/tOnTObjEwgLfA@HDC3BBhH3Cr9Whe@etWxidmooNIWD5VB4Clymtq4Fz7LGPLfwFrAKIYOkRXmEzGL6GlPieqJnIRGCdtMTQwxKbjp1lwEP8moC8RVeEgrMKzYRw8IMSnOzGeOdj@VFN3WLcktz2Ti6J592TPO@G68jc8dRRNHNP3oHT4rMr7/nXD4uBfFwAct8PaQMt0CSxjt5VXYMEQ8AUFWna3BJtQRVipvmuYAdC8oOd3hlpyXsX5ygiJC4EM5l4QhbF8KxSBqXj1cDMYd2HmI3oOOWTuHJdyiDR8DiyWU7WqHJSaeXmO6CQMjEi7LuRakCgtevyuHtuolJP1kJBfJoW1ul1NSCVNZxdlbgLi8G@gj3Nhdm2cNsVMBtl0al/MNExXuJqZiCMp@bmcATMBfy@fWbcM/mIgiu/KK4eR8yyz/9/gDG9xOU3tij6X2g3MPH6cB/QgBLio5vlQ8azExAEHXm9ClTeafOKJo@SAufF4LEoM5ho4vXgk3HmmSjmbTNx857pCh2ArmWh0gTDjPKW8210r9aHh0y5BvjW/nw@HhjQyDcI3j1s/BwXUTpSsQJD5VOu5muaxMYP5bUd/D4GJ1GWnpmjg7N8Q2tPDPoScts0Qy0xSEjvq02HUwxUCQ0q6jiNYI4qVeendVTtHI0hweHD/fZGmmra09NQcqunIywnBXLXpYAYr00HYG9Bh3F@8grwQ/SkA5QQjHRobwElU3yxrRRiYCwXKNbHsS2T8FStdlKb3uGbqMGkLRMd3DfhYA0@bp/dJCcN6GeLU@Fh8R5AzsBodKyosoUFNxwHhcxTaPgtYnukX5KwmsOxAbJJZcO6xmtmC1sSZQ7O@2n@7WtenrNqMgM@lzd7ntD96J11nG6523WY4NXzZExfvOasfwGW0ddk3e5qkytUMFzqwmG6kWKbCtLBCsSuEPKSE9lxlTStIjryWwy/C6vsCQZaKxcwhMQM1TK1voBFeJJOb/SrxXqFbuSLfdrdr2MZ/X8VMVPaakEOtyFzhNYC1@Qr/l17Ep/Fp1tNe1z5g6bYxglhWc/GJ39wP4dZ7jEnm2aL6dtxtId3KyGZ0hU27xIhFeqI2VKKP9Id@gQj4bnwmm6GGdbWhakAEo/DcKqN6L3OCndyarDge@Qj4hIQRJib6230p3g1FGWJgwApGbVg@RsE54JTALXfbjrmO@GVjQujWl41DEZQVHDkMTt5FNZxiOAmFBx9KpWlzzV1I0uJgKvznxLwdj2Nl2kCSTlqTRJhzs1dJcOPmTraMT1DfgMaDEBoyDB3KPjGxJkH@0aGrgLTUH5dN6FNrpLJAiiD27jZpd0HInCb0MB8IK/w0UqVcxgCsEK5ER@1I/mDlDx3PS4HlcR8BQkr5Q7mFnEzeOrTJDTjm8qI4xWFBO437nA4uRlBY/IgaKR7Vo2QvgkB6cioWVoYfOwLKlKyauKn94kWCISTAmCBcCRorhzY2ngRBaMfh6Z0HzGbM/s9SDRvCzuTIoDjXQcV8SfCuP3ahhnPUw891eu@StT/ir354maQKnQf0@ASlEgOXY5gbti8gQsfS2uCiPZRIWaNlSQOCaw5WWwnuo7DWsCXA2rklNl6LE95aFEfF7MqX3uszIVJiTw0L/G/QV950TNh6mcgr03HT9@JVFBJu2NFVtJZqhUta3eDu@cQh8kMxlKkzEeHOubyI43SnFkUrATENBwGp@abbUywZLSAo5DbUaubt@TVSFM7CRmk8EPHV5rWHPaSKSUKM4UFdyIzhdCPOS9EkFBOJHQWNByq0HgsQg8jqBFqJUgWn5o8VoDh6zNNvEKHmN8i6@gsU8nLoCLzfe8w1M@4pnnh5GnC4iY7oo8v5imuQke@@COIlNLepFJ3ONZjPOZxOPIJG8Yp8mPTLdxlnsl5BNRRhFwimvlHvqIkp4AaAH5LqpC9LySfpZZkz7WQYQe9MwR28VRhE6nqaSp8@ioi9VDLUmksMUbDgY9XFQkwe6CTjwLxR25PK6mTDBGltFU6RA37nD4NJrE@XEIpLIjxHyB@z8mHt6wgxd647oNKkcC1ooTKpavSrv2mM9XQJtZz/FT4SYbenxRFAbznWgieM3x1oMl7Q10w1QlkMU8kHIkntU2b99iuhyPhaCeLujSSpL0taFlnO19jMu1m1p2XYsU2blY7c2q6xuTg1JQSIFHLgvial7bkKTI0q/Bl34VRJhmD7Gj/xxo0zzHa6OlXegxCNAD4dQz3XOzpUrSUzNc40W8SMq48IjHpp2ha/C5G5Ct8LppPO37/7b3bNttI8k9m1/RBm0RkHi3rqaoGUqixpzIllekfImkpUASpDBDEVwCskh7lHOSh/xAPiCfkod8Sj4kqUt3o0FRluaSndk9O@eMBQJ9qa6urq6qrqoOs3zaBRSGf3F/5tPgLh2FZVN4JhUfJsNUf/J7iEAVUNIP8PCXziMwqp/xgZWuvAiQsuyIJEh0tCxhIdnlCu1MgA1MS2IcPWg0jILI78LMkKEqNYSm@JQj7mzUm4ME@usOXQzyzS8CAKNfYgwoANRJ0ddgSMkz8Z8Fg5ADU0forpqZAnC/gNYKLHdv4gP3jRFMs0LVDNhhgluvGk3RPDpova8d1wU8vz0@etfYr@@L3Y90hI3n4JQcVrw6OgTuog/L@VD8CF5YtSbUtOhDqvbmo6h/eHtcbzbF0bFovH572IDWoPnj2ptWo97MisabvcOTfTpchxbEm6OWOGy8brSgWOsoS72qaqm4njg6EK/rx3uv4Gdtt3HYaH2kHg8arTfYGR7a18Tb2nGrsXdyWDsWb0@O3x416wIHltpvNPcOa43X9f089A99ivq7@puWaL6qHR7ODfTo/Zv6sSAfAGOUu3WAsrYLqir2ROPcbxzX91o4oPhpD5AHAB5mRfNtfa@BD/UPdRhO7fhjVjbarP/pBArBR7Ffe137DgaXsh/ACszL3slx/TUCDZhonuw2W43WSasuvjs62idcN@vH7xp79WZFpA6PmoSwk2Y9K/DaKuoa2gBswXd43j1pNghvjTct2DNO3qI7gwOT/B4QA1DWoOo@IRi9HHC0gKSj44/YKuKBJiAr3r@qw/tjxClhq4ZYQIeJvZZZDDoEJLbMYYo39e8OG9/V3@zV8fMRNvO@0aw7MGGNJhZooL/FRyAd6PSERo3zBHDxIxBrSlFulqZTNA5Ebf9dAyGXpYECmg1JLYS2vVcS57CWCynDWOIHaBtwr0wDSv/uq08eZnW8a3lZbIvRCY72jvbrsCPL9FFW/OEEdp3NucxH5jfYafRH@JnIMNPzOteDtj/qBxgrqquxgeMqHGTxVg4H1HNxlvrKxSzSjkIV0ul2@12tDYpus912so@pmQDjoRrSyv21Uo4cI@aIR80bDTwvXzLetxOI2lmS55jkh4fnC1iSsb/Enm3uleeIQqHnyWoYhI8NKxNRyKcil3hSAqyRYhnxPoq4S7JA0G9fkgNVtFXz@W4bzaDo@EiFghD@Gf0U/@DNwXgB3JnNWoUCKrEEhv/ZU91wJ5TagP6RmQX8PnWZDz3vx4FdNLtDnT8/CIKe7TiqDpWNQA8c2M4D1TveYK56br4@AUunyjK1fKj0bhJh9PGyRJmQ85Kf0Mhs/Kcd0R9HQcO5G9AoSl2RLVoaJ@0lro4OR1khU1Rg9ARNMsp8r2sfGu9RmyuWVytz71/p97y20B0Q89LChndK9c7pz6tzLgALjHJqAEp8memiUDDqKHcSXfgGCl5iIcq9T3v1pUf7OqAEBNlrd2j2ibvxxJ@a0AMf/u649nr35OAAWCdCu7q5trFeSeksWR@y/Pcj9kPZUilJ2Bj2cZDT6JOxSvZA8KGVYqTYjsmfCLhQwIKYxFxNGr3EfA3aLSPpqISMDIcb4uUsI/TAszzEgyUokcbTlKLXhStTEoCdGKqDo7lypyTiuyArEQ1IX5XhjGZtiv9g23r5qyWuByQJSJIY5agFygXtgviedaA8QUm5oTw7WCRvKTrmrGsaB2TqIvdYDJ6lX5K2jVkM2VMR1ytNO9UEIJ7OQyGU28SIV/ZbyhciDb2U7AvefJD0Bo8fZT46yk7nhlEtagIaD3RNtEfHRmc56FPZ8vlOFaZoaUn3tC3Qmu9IoGjtSbOxTvBhrAYC5Rx9BqtiruGKzgcy3yU5uH6bccQXplRMwoHtVCTFyt9AuYuGI1upqDwg8rfKLiG4LZ2shLF2o/tIqSIfdT4Khc4Emn4VPqj93xEnC9rfBo0TWo@xZeTsexQmqVXGFaivhBT/Rh0oGKcYMTbNVx/jZm7NibnUA5OnNFMOnwEUyNmZqRcfKUth316AACRyNGyY61d7nF26oDp9azmyOp6HjLpXY1vIvUJtFXfaza2fZ0nsyqozFPzhCIdtTUaHh1BVfMuKW4dWPahMc6q8eB5a3Jyj8ngUlskAohc8UeklO6XOU1ZRrjLFB2TKJGPD6enMRyCW3t57OrcsjIyWCd4vT7gUoqDpHYTn7jgpp3kg2Ps2mSCRc6i3KGkdptVGNRk3H5lhrkN@lkMP23neI2MIXjob3eAGMeTWKbNe3Jqwn5MfCHYSOxXGaQGR3Tp5QC1tqzcaerJMIoVq6E9GnJzeY6uWKpHn/B0SQjMaPi9euzMAefi4YTOJFZabQRZdE7EzNkvI@njBbjcIJiA6ujhugDHrz5y8eC@NDt4ovJ7IdIOwn/kTaZFQQj90g2ITa@@0zXAedAIt9CMMRujliT5oSFceOoBy9pFpbl3YQLyKRneU0dGfrpSEvR1/2QacUBZRQuK2WBc//cSlGKEyw6dHGPRDrVyQSyb1g@cOevndBJMfce9HEWjU83o6kajRJNkCeZIaI0rJ2I146OMgJIsGTAVaQDQmSmxI036osEdvSHKSbktWnMwSU43SSH5@P5pIlTMUdBQTruwdiG89B5OJWCrLTJ46t2epvEagLFK4bu9Vxii5Z/J4WlhnI81SXrIQUX2uREd8Yr6pnz7ikzTyV5@HuHrgDZ5lSxEUAUaZFc9P7/I5gg8T8733vUnPtImCJNNzx2h@I9UnGBEtKtOhTN/XdaPQm4EG0C340wK10ba/Dy5H7b1g6A78wHdBT8OE6FPmePg4o0ecsMEkuAnpHh360DMK9WbxM6eP4XRq@FufS1aMFFth5I1t0x0hmsxql5wFgizn6OMn9H5F9D2ez3Wm66yuxZVSyfBScrcrOZV7674oLarMJ/fYgGRwO3OeEhwiGlHckRFbWrlToPO1AgaMHZETrnOPQ14C4i1AER3DJCBWwNxxPzAHgZrZvRCf9qbZHuUSnGAeJW/fw5toQpteZ128gBW4yDfoEfBSlDaLRlU@RZliPkF8mN2P7vLG7ww9APArwC@9WEQtiwiBWFxfJVMKWV@RSUEBFvL@84lHEycGLuYPYBcaJhptT@dbTX6e3YcN8vABoUimy7tDlbgibVB88Po1uw0spz1zcFPJiIxDaTlQBKlFdvF@gvUeco@lxY@HuGw5Q8a0J1u2DaDvQ1UXsISXas55z5ogcwrkh1dMufzYWZtDYHWRR5lx34NtKcmFAkx83l/xWCuYADO25rAnXT0yYRSMM4/E3r28Y2GGtUW47jrOg36@TGxV2CyXe4Ta6gwfZ5XUPDxzRJPEGHmUAQ2h@krPmsznkTittnG9VduzB/BwH85i/yi9qej57vHax03xEzrsqo1GLymCHZONVvT70zYMvH0/B5FtsnrVJo7RRpbRnvGj0dQcmjSWHo8hoj4J@xw@eoA57LcHuDPn516kzjvDqdSl6lMiWSXiE/OsY0wm8KVxH50vMAscS7iaSWmBc5qd0VFeKdfBZMH4gRtEqdjLxXYotuDGkzVHR5TMv2@30VuohJwInnZMDwedo18jjJLoS@OO9Hhoz3Kl8wq3NNUtgVZBpb7Wkgonh5@n7Sm1cgcVsMQXoEKP6A5vunz8qH7tWKActMC16bN05C1mcTCOWAFo4B/zU3uKMnDclayZWFHJhdAm1gBrAbSUwdBjdRWlP3/CFI/eDXIZgQLBr238syJrYPbt9aLGNlaZ9mZYxJHo5tXmiNwOV4kJin8j@uVSZFGXFFdowGOIoX61BC1gelKCHg8FKLOOSXkJQOUcQcVqCZclvKTsprE/54LviFRZYHXNKFFcVGLLbCO3sBEQLBaXiQEBmWVxkbgV2OgWwmKU2Fg8nrgECMSK9hnjMBVyVpI41DPHCIRHglZzlNOSyBYlBdPH1TUn8VHTN33dKhpfi/NfAT8awtNcaf7rZjHxNdFtuZysmqgJ@HDMXhMfARWOCbDmCr/uP4o8MVOXa59QQ8lISBnSD3uEqtQN6m35H0KxTTHXSsZQ7ZmB30r9avONKInk6l9PpC5kmv7Krx@sckxVgMjM/pR1ToWy2KwPksBq4U6Po0JFV@XR0@kHlEob9MW71sFBIqlrZ6b8jK68yVqxWEQa7pg57JULNVqS/KCQLF3oXw@HhfHN95N3nQKxfrzAfhgGL5UC7cGMwJoI88FkwPc4IAxQFEvnZJgqqvrX/b55YQIeUOLcwaxxSZnrQND@42ufl3ctsv9Qk3J/vcAB4vguhF58Ny7LmbIVdQoFtdEj@JOlDs8APfiij27Y@qCKGkO@rJyZYNtyqjtfcAPBe0hosigLsfMl9k62XnnDYZAV74PJsId5AJ7czlc4ODArFLkIHjBS7O51SNlms8L75A@NqGEsYpI6Nqf2JXUrhErvjinuj71BfTq2rdM/W7CrwJBXcJgrmGY6K6yB5cic749olukQwH5U6St3bHcJT/OFYaeXCzh@AohelLILVZ9EEYdMYhJnD5dGpC4GN0@pGGDoDokCKiU9TS@N5J7iGrnW2bTURxwWuQ0JE2ZUeVwNDCT7/bjip6jffxxTpGz@PLF/dYZIRwC0AuXyA3xiMux/ysGyPphLF8LyDd65cZfvYIU2Vkilnnerf7mxa7WaeDZeWRG12i485HKitlsT@/hid1fsw@9d/L1ULa@tVZjn7jtf4OWuenkrdqENMnCudC8n@/ATvlUxKgydtXGKnxWqz7KVZ@3q9k4lLJzWdjFoH57@51///X/@7T8KNfnjP/HHLv04/bMulM/nC8@6X54t3Vbw9@n@eeZZ5/TZ@DwzqCCVIbs/mYTu0DW8R/Pd1AMRUr2h37kvakp7z/ghuWqiu6QN/1SroIH99BM/nUXx4yR@xJyocXV3OL50qbqgFnaqmVpmaQmetquZf86Q7US@d/X7z/BeOMjLKWkCoRbv/RG15l6jYaYdR65P0nvfwxw5eNOlzJcjD64u0upawNypyOfFeU5caPDQzaPNBZMgsprJwPyLBFKNjnxy6Oxaqg14KE2mbzbH88HUVTgg@U6ZzvnyM1dqKs97L/kMjdpYAYaH5Svsqy7jXnH4AC4ee1Vzp6X1tfNcOp1O6QvR2l1ic9TbmPrSF2SpI3TKz8BhWGNYMjB2uqCuiriABhEZ6TRdl7XU5Wvd7BGq1qQxscKdzhjyPNqbaCApzebYws3JFFDGQoWPriAT4TVFYaBsMHvsGR4AQOF128S4BF@VHI69rt@faZcHvJEi7h32SgyZWxb9OxFzwpp0LDmup/24QUAISgGUqwcbnW@QkRdAWZ@4HY9R/QZx4y5RXcjk32KVJlg7BI2D4WwwhM5scqUKb4A7AeYdOVnDkQqlwx64ZscDqceTK5onLPblRbg7HpoiRl08IcP7oYaYk4sFPj7@pWyUsB5QwpH3w/UxFMQejtiBKOjDI2z4GEXHR1hEhiu4pUqCQqUWlWN1v5zkA8tjxxFjLolYhd/x4TuRB5kgSR@WF93JNCF8GjN2ZE18uy0pbYxX@6EiLXODOnIlWbRW9OkbSJVXeFaJ55SAFCyZp7vEgDXMxMVwdKHHz6ebIV5HmLdUl9xNmf0TgGPpblS4PHXHsQAWG1fp5jE84ZS3ZQdh6HcAWTBEOU2UApGDBybQ6lkmxZ1JasHjQEQwvloe6xVljk@RkjcdU3w@w/sETbsjRQWJgnhAimdiHp7dYY6DQLI8@DUKRjliuR0v8rvsQMm9P1W8eIzn4nRMSYDd3xEoDy6OU08w9XCmsgvJ42Ka6rgdwhMGK@D6v9Sit0s4k2ZeyaJl4AgApIlDz85ZjKS4RU0J1EASKRJG8v@WGHySIMyhN/CjRJ2szMDAbuc8iluFelzkFwiwid05zGKghDpp1izhQuJbuWYg41XfgNFuOjL4eRHtqcHgrsYXT@qaPCSKp9u8Sx@aHylwTKhhBQP6cPlmkzNEmyvudZREDlN59pKkKuJZ@GoP1LgEkfnFMgX4UAOSW8zjJHcK2CjPYQPY6dwyiLlwMdG8QcBI3OZOTjxqDr08XSwS3GHeil4UpEgEtykd0vPl/7vfxFR2JhifDIsPSiEdwB4dO5zoPBrzTS5cgTeeEtRlcjxgjZNrzEjHjixyR8EUNj4vUqNTDcdcV2rocoZzJCmNKT8K/DzNmHM5V1WNN659nqydy3BI1xcV2GUbks7YkfFe8usT3sxhN1XtcsQWHb3Rr1sVWiYjs7TDhJodiXLaXt0@ogcdYuiOJT05t4tIQ@nwisurMUvJAoTLROPUFh3RyHKmT9ACJLGvQu06ChrRby/TU25pedanX9J1qyAXuCAGSxHBdQryCR7R@9j5rdQC5AM@MAL2X3NDD55TKZY8pIZpvQ4Hu8HULmbPrDMrW1rfcizSk7Uclu6GoBmlux5nS8MrG6XuSVkZya79yWMWPun4vZ43UrlYoarsTX9qy2ZP0Zz/RbO7kG@4tYiJe5bBy8McTCK9kLim5/HEHVy59PgmaE3cWQM2Ifp5NOL5bGJ7x7AZ4Z1M9OWY12itB6KGdYt6ckwTjxoieUW5IPl0IxINOBOfIS4sQIB3BwHcpx5/mBysgQZz/Gy70NIz7ZswqRcsoYTsRH3BBycXKb7w9wpvpG3zO6BN27gRWD7Sp7lrqqWMgB@Ug7DxlmuwqD/Ekx5vlDiHUKmDJeHxtdFcKyuGQKBFpXJ9fSgB@0NfaOjDC6nYRN3L9tX1MPLlyO4MS40LK83ffUzqpLqu@p77j8lkOI87YxzY7qkPqzTWZYhRxViQSphqxdAfFbpp/GR2jIUGqapw2o/yKtFH8bbylblh6X5HqRqYlcM4sFHKKY4zZagbULuSivdZoUf9NKF8IByAFARjeUwXTxNrvjXnGGcY84YQM9GT@9fQ2f@WlVx@Q6cNMZaUXirdM5mHxbo@RRVkRVEeYhtaLVAK3zweXHlSs5XqhKG8GrfGcTLN311hfUBzS0h/BqqU17YpuzxNLLSEcKj8NQ10aiGGdmZzFmispjBiShLEcsYyMQLjWbZ0y1HpC9kGKyVQkmGeF7KVxKRHuoC9QRN3Ns@sFiPufHKU9KYlICoKNNVTTFXubvHGJv190aoX72AK1qRMaYrsIt5AY5l1gRKuyeBBRHl3EVX6ZYhiuBbhib/8ZmhKIiCJpdtUahH5atYhXbPMta4jiO7wJULcUy0Iz7WxQNDtDDFpYAzYfHMwgUqy31LC8LKoDYAtJmVhdgx343es9bACGc6FjGtDHIchXE8wqW4apKsU/I8JjoFLXaFBJ2EBAZG1kNKFKD4MsUH41tYImbJAFNJOSvoMFdJ8TVBpo@RQJ4/oCSNwf4V4z2wQj2L6d4LfcEMhkWNZtGUA4cO7H@1195ilE@NbaJIGjhwbpZk9L4/HGFTwkJW6kJapLGwBzQtH/EIDNdlKyrwHoZ2nkE49ARBY0sCcetAZ1V6RBt7Qg2HojJxszo3dsFg/VIbuP5L9W@FY@SpICtACQlFJByif0RXQPMFSQqBAVlqgmedhBlCtY2cW9hKLaiQuEmoTlKx28JLcqhcahPSs0C4divgG1UlkWBUXWk2VhUikF1YTNqYYRWsGHR15XTSEaytV6Bj2YGl2KEDb8kZuAIsDJXWTCXZlDmdpSUjYyGQ9J2MsVPQTiGI4Esg4G8l4iznSBSaELwnxckuBZaKlvvFC@wMXkCXi1bm0WBBB9hrLIbGFphDj/XqkMb8YO1T1a/ihYIhgLt6IcEIcVed@iaFJ/VyEzuPzASIlg97fDpX@rJl4LKnKe7vvo0XeizdKvBebe88sLKC1AXcf/Ot3Oc6XAkvj/Ucsm8HXT3j/JTMF/MMESvEKkU4iANw@jBx51/iTWK/Lh1Gbr03X7Bf1OOly1@vBdgzMlgKasqAnRuSDJAw8KwdbSjDwszZMpaRz95IVgoqJoMxrZrJ2rJcJUswM9VdlJSBM9WUY9xNojtyLKJITj66CLucFgA0Kv/cpKwDptSVWi1Ah4oqn@FPGVD7pc5rCvlzJPAKx3JbdyjFIeGgQLGPtTtzoUSJWfCTHDvtihEmiQMqap8MwnxKNny@SPUYuW360XJZeJpv2ciyeLafHIFu8@IVt/HXltNhAC@1YGnILFyoZ8EnlABTDBA3Rwzg25kuuZR65/XKx7x/iyx91Y1j@w4svyxr93aQQsxwLMd2FQkxcQNbqouGN6unyxB5g2Y5IQ16WYg/3FyT7g3Wj@gsW9sc3sYu4nKwcULf4ekG30U0ga2hClR2S/XFhR8hreU1fWHJtXwj77oLm@Y634Rf/2Ib/vrfhgsYFZht9YKcxpv4fc//3MPeYv3K4Wdwstn@zc1/9zjIJy5o7bxXCeipKO99snE33i2fTrdWjv6Sj9E658H4Cf6P0X9Lrm2l@hAf49UL9@pTeSW9jsfXb9KxQrVbhUbZSO4BWdr7XbWKp2Tb8s7Om2l2fpXdyVar@U3pnHR5K5TJAcjatb51NN4v4v1X5I4kf5umKFj7ua3VMOW3khsBngdJFntTyIIyb3DN2hwaSgFLHkwZS3Pmh0RwBjM4z0/JmUcoqQECc/OGTJ@/fUmkzpPxI@WMiymjCERcq7YP01eNKsAJ0Fw78oS5ot5eiV5xwQuWaQCkhBlpcPM@v49H1hcxBoQHQ@SZIzGRXblAvbOoY05vh353iN5bOR/HSSiTBSJ5tyl1xU@6K/5sW41l0GYzKC7Lap8UeTFfkiR9ChiUc@eOxF7HEP/BG3oRSmcBwUNDBa/a6eCnh0P@R3f9eqsZFlxpq/xC2OTaHG8qPZ8J69i2sLP@KtKLPsCrVM56Pra@qX8C48cI2jJNR0TUDP7q87tCFBK3JrBEdUSaKAiY1jzgrRQFkuU7hykXHAUrjHwKJQQlgB5PrUYEudgOBDWNlMPf@lfsjgIaXycLQem0ohsb@H226uTX0xhTiMu33LbomyRv2mt7YnbicsQ695q/dgdfATDwwGeGlhcpTWryh4JrITE2slSXCOMjh8j6sHGcPI94fZlT4J6FWCAw3put6LIxTl0yIeLeVp6gJqGVxaAFdEd4Pgiguz1HjugL9TNagfGwwSRwagoeD8YiAm@P4VxQQK0LIFwRH/FN2Gr@gjgiaifDxGg0clTe6viLa0dfanpZensucddWScb04ebxuvpRXylsWIhSnSRqbS5v45Zp9L@lcMiVTB@hxgGDNkEBBnpBrOi28Ak0hDIPOD5RoCbkSLEikv7z6Jpc9udHDIxq7R97AJV5x08FkPPC254dUAGsWBp9BdmcUZROk2rkehHleCxRY4Yfhtbe2sblKANGOr4r2gm6iaLkALU/cyaxAwF1GV0M9iq3oUgy9T95Qeq8Q2JTOlxcl0RneaOZeD8mtZd0h0gFUJkYKWLC3svxuv35wWGvV97Mgpqxh8ZDCknRZ20Auf16h7/0hZmpgMsIqvHzznfVVJnI7zGa@RYscg/6tifYVE2DVQBjmcQ/wx3amStWknwU3LMaoto8GWX0cTqmGVNZoXG4IyjVdNWEp5KqVn05jSFeIfaWRBBOJDaAODkxFbk@GwHjuFLqXVwAGJHdrR0CRQ@SfSLnW9tNcTq@pl/SUA8aay@2wkcXaG/qgeGaOr0cJbpuhteOKDDA5PP5n1vY0Q3whb1XEZRX1@Eq3WqzouL1P9rXzRV9J3UcobEZcK9idqfmzr2VkmgUIccjLWYVM/vd/ZZzKbZxEZ2hHDl69ID5XVeboPDP1Ot9Va2fCLkxWBNU@5yNvGu1xps9qVNEVOkFvlqfkWr090Kp79mezj7HtfIG9emWlW62@cL5Al5MxZgAdAzP0WtCiU8F3/cQ7HSJWODsb4QXUyxi69@H14SuYcvQT88Lo9M/ny88K2UzGcSo4BLdK8X37R6/fopV/4uTJ2n8wCa4kXiau7iQPs30VnhbPCfqshUMr4CoEzjnwIjn6cHfWcgdvQFqyMy6gAN2SKDAOJsXfdmV8WQV9k1DmwstZTBxVreTkWs6XQZVKXU68foVtFbdh9ZM9cCoR/Lk0u1iDLqrlMrUeQaUqejXNYd0fwW79qvX6sJrZdgW2Wl2wKjIrHU0cQChEMDa@quF1VAnSAa5CVBVxtB4RDPy3krF2kmPZLrg7mcrt7b3wHHI@XRB@MjEB9@zrrKS4SfXulFYmMRXMxl4VX/DW9l29ZWWhLqZgwZcj3N5mxLQ4iLWq@mByQ05BW@CsiWWq1dWlJXqHVa7DarVcLDqYEeUWWgvx/nholhfWpHI7cas9WyPSHfsLbksq58sFDmQJC6X1cnFt45tgAltEFS@kXwqBhVRRa/nkR7MlkA29qrp5aQnkZNhNq09XlzeP/N0/fdhqru/b3c73JStr/RCS2/5kbAIwcW/yLBYBj53IXLsEBEYudt3C2P0xKKz2il2QPEsbPW9jzdssvtjsrnkvtjpbW1vd/upmp7e14W6sdTsFTPZOVfJX/gikJIvJH7vtP67b@wSzzXJxq98vldY3emtb/a1y8cWL1c7mWq@4utrfLLkvXqz3ypudrc7XpbYYnhQwWMV3ce@Y58DP7xfuUnd4u6zt/B8)

We already have Trefunge-98 answer ([#76](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127128)), it uses PyFunge interpreter.

PyFunge uses Python's arbitrary-precision integers, and [`2y`](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#system-information-retrieval) returns cell size `-1` (infinite). CCBI uses machine integers.
So PyFunge and CCBI can be separated with `2y1+_`:

```
@,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@
```

Comment: Milo's Wierd may be preventing GNU Pascal from being added. I deleted answers 287 John's Wierd and 288 Milo's Wierd until I find out the details.

Comment: Yep, they clash. So the Wierd answers will remain deleted, I'll add Pascal instead.

Answer (score 2):

## 287. [Refunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Refunge), 13305 bytes

````html
#16 "($?63lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--2$[# #@$]aat_"  /*{\D8gv ef26q[if.q8=P,k]PPX~_~^)"xv"y\('#CO|"14"  7 9 7 9                                      7 222222222222222222222222                                      ##*/
#/*1&7//```"`     [>.>        .]~~)['][7aat_                        '(22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ;#####]#######++(- #### ##-[######??mxf####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8               ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退              @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
#>x   >>IF 2>2*>      18&1&    nthteo nthie \#184O@  nthneo anet    @.7.8.2 /112\ <  ##### #######   # #    ##### h#115#  o#    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#W\aa*7+42@n;WWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
# 36!@`D//<> ++++++::@\_       / 78"oo@"    xx   ; L         >"082",,,@_   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
#comment -[v]>>>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>>> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx [>]R 10G|'53'S 101111xxxxxxxx # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#~// x    v>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ xxxxxxxxxxxxx [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9xxxxxxxxxx #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[]]x   >>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>R.-;---.>>>>>_xxxxxxxxxxx #v
#- ! ++R+++  +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U+.._+++++++._++o+++o--ox #
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*_+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;; +;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#{  
# []-main=-[165]- ### M MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  //:1*23/5x%6E2
#cs  
#2""/*  
#|9999 9 9
#9 999 99 9999 9
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9
#<<<# 9 9999 bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24; exit}} __END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;WW;w_;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1*)echo 242;;4*)echo 78;;8*)echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0*)echo 282;;*)echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{a='//'}={a:null};console.log a&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89; exit#ss
ifdef x 
#  
#  
#  
#  
# *#p 173#* //:
p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiocr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;ee ecisajjarpppppp vwWWWw⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
write 224;Bye ;
0 0 
0 0 

♈  
♈♈  
♉♈   XX//:
♈♈   +------+XX   X       XXX #>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]*****<
♈♉   |/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈  |/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
♉♈   |/0010 | X
♈  |/0011 | 
♈  |/0001 | 
♈  |/$0011| 
♉  +------+ 
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
1<<<< ! !
2<<<!<   !
1+``  +!!
1=  *
53  +
1>  *
51  +
#
1+  *     xx+   x  x
49 x+  xx+xxx+  x+x + x B+ ===+
x= xx x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
x+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
x==+R _*=x==  x +x==+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
`+ x`=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
x  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
xD~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  **************************************************+  <>
  +  +$$$
  <>"3"_O._+// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +    e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   +   +;*
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
#= #= #=+
^#
 #+=    #
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+   231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
#  
literally, print 249
(print 164    (exit ) )
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}                @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run(putStr"159"  )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa




























































































































































































































































































































































22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
<script> onload=function  (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test(f )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
~~~x
main:Int
main =248
~~~ 
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57 ent
set ! 51 ataw;#8;""[ x]mint}=>+;dnu91&&1Prers 6 4>80::\0;}ngt=Bk:pext sep*sEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:2FACbody+/='d  #  +- $在e*n*""; 16 ""6
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet */
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=! '(',y[60];macro m( ){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77   );}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y );x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(  ){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
`WWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW. :-write(186). end_of_file. `WWWWWWWWWWWW<<<<<<<<<<
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;{-_vwWWQTkTTX-}import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad  (Const a )where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k   (0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))- (-q?6+70+z));(! )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
 console.log 178;
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
#endif
p=sizeof("(\");print'(''72'')';end !");main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
print 61
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#"; print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}} #@[[[["272"?]]]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155")
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;@,,,"285_";# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51 @!00:8:8 ;;~nJQ p'34'   \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 :  Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2)#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208   )#sCOprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//   >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\             \n*n*es*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js*   <e 5>1  *///\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1dcyNLdhj43OX9B/uSLPA2AAJVQIEECAIE2Gw2eS/v7W72NNm371wQjS4UCkA1gSp0VYEEms2OmfHurMbSeuXxWDGakXVH45VXWjnCWodtjdaSHSG9OhR@0g9ofWxsKDY0/2D2nJNZhQIIgOwZTcQ@bJGoyo@TJ79Onjz5dbKpe92f/SyGD3vi9MadnuMz3/R81nKtc9NV2f0xu6dbXj63LkkItet2hn3T9r2SFGMaY7Z5wQ5tw2qBG/OdM9O23pgu@OUYG7hOx9X7zO/qPlgsCMUemL23/bc@M5x@X7dbHkCuM/ZEB8/20DhjetPzXd3wLccGrw3Gntk9vd9s6QwgTHfgmj6hzzNAYZxRmGmfAmOPHNczMXrD9DwHHTcZ2zb7A39cBUsRIHTXch7uPv54JvAWYx/rkLJBzxzNpEXLsueW6bZmQmga@/zk4GDWNcc@UxybHVxPn7bOnrme3tNn8W@w3aHvHPqz7nm22zFtneXULTU361lg9139WpBN5pp6q231TNWyDaawrtkbmC5DF9Z2XKgy3@wVs8VsY3cSUjUwbHHiOYO2EjxMdzseeDrnJhhNqImBZbZY23X6TLe9C4hJ28pO4BHt1jQ5GJBAIDT2yoPQLZN5tjUYmD73hOyaLnlDzKxn2WcSp74nrtMaGpbdATgTynUw9ClPnmRAsCobCBpW0cBiVAocDJJw7PTNaF14QLyQam9gGlbbMnjhmCPftD3Ir6cyC@ruwur1WMvsQYAJdiPNPIcNvYhTs6d3VUOVsHAxFtY/6zGLGYMB416QDUjSQbbIzL7zymJvwL/X9dho0Gee1Qdv33DabdNkb8xBF4KzfosZY0NqORKDxxjM5C60rZoAY5uQw70nX4ey87FI7TYkr8WaEThIC6Wbcq3bDhShy2y9zynCGIypBABNGKLtOCq6txzTs@M@u3DcM9Y0DR2zjpF5ZqetD3sQo9XGKgFasDzWd@ALFWkzSBYE9rE8EDdGJs3NCEYTVLE5gMaJVewgyUB9BzV94epAI64n6tK3@kAhlh/3mKl7FnItCOKZdouoYxDyMwdyG614dm5B44OiGLqE2zNdIn/CyzAXgFIP6TVx4Vo@UAXmYpc9MXWXnbimmeS0anqGPkBKjUYJkTkYg48ZUYk4t7fj@0cHcSBSHkLVB0CU7vrJ1z6VdKZW2GqjDL@KLJel/ccP2OXqKZo53wRCHrgJPckq75iXOT014TfSmpmOeyUBVglKpccyzsDP6MoAEqj4kMCMjkY0Kec5ddCLRMy2Z@og0nQ4VAtqAxgB@zxNOTOGroscflKo@hlkuufYHShPyKw7tHmVF7JQBUB/LS/NzHMTaYDXkXNBJXzSBQqBfwCNcBfe6VCBQrcDzVGUaBCv5/SGBAchPR/bJJQKBEWMh232OWvrVg@DgD@i4ql2TQ@IE8MM7RbWfN@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@ftICsKZ11of27o6ZYSITAW5i8h4CIxlSg/JAmGVOm2WVXD4/3WiutRnfzewqXwLXfZNZ2jQw89HWgZyDtUF27ul2Z6h3oEk4NgTRDcMc@ILzQE48H3jLbAdCjoroDVWvK63em42beoVA5pnEQe2Hak/0bTqyCyGLKyBooTzHBXzWgkZpUDOYjh0Azmcil18iyFQCXsoLkhB06UBkvJVD4wYCvuha0EovKHU2Z3S8V5mNHpyisQOrVtph1JgYrXo3J6mZ0AmTsRCFgjV6HQ/0loiqOuVAlR91WI5Z9/pzEDthEoGzR1zVjK4C7d2As@/YzhykUJAhWgSZ9uH1AKLVMUq60BMFchQ11lD8DasI6gy4BrR8oL@u7w@8EjB@y@8OmypQSubEHR/6RzYSS8Z3x5bvcHOz5zQzfd2D9pkJYsgYw6Y1mskQuYV1@MqTzkGianuswpD1AtUl4m0P@Ca57yFwxEsmKYdQ8LcMgASkQkEl2h6x4gNgKsdj20jIU0Qpp5mMbVdOggEDhkXzKUpj08l8BU6zqUSwaGLUDEJlPNcggxIRMhE9glOypDtTWbtlGqU7sgyvtt7zTPjaw14PrUObc7kE7/yT7FK6cwdYW4Kis/qDnmVYfoP7srt3hZDAVmDghnJQG4WgJIS5I0bIKjAUgBG9D4dWfeeYpNdEEjJy52oqYtN1HZfH63dd6NTJAcGkaKE@ts6GrZlStdENi1PGMQQKyIYPEi@Mr7jcM0ME0yU12/eyOJYUkgqG50yzwmSBj6K6RjrkijUmi2BCSKyIpEWqMIEpSnO8ADy3tHho4RbN/J7Tx66NPSfxEccDMFC3bJywkLhYQVKFPleqCAUKkv7jcfWVY9mJy/jKykq8FK@CuLCysgOmbTTtoCkFph0yKWRCOBVNFCJNJvStUQh0q8evagHmUbKOvGCEQ5w31iCh10ql9Xpar2nim8NvEogMukuAVvADeOLJSgWNyaRcvYCMqs32dO73sMs/NlxrIArhU/1c53ZRCutUDEC1jot1UcYyX14m/Yprqh4MbYxuwo2f1rKn9dPL01bq9CqextDJsl5pQqYgvkRf7bjOcJDIJmsbJUWrJ5O1dRDFmpV4Nr6WSBQVGJTCuCr5UTGZ0nlpJ@ImiAKJ09M4FKoon5rRdQnfKJ1LJsOignSgtAcjh0RcvSxC/M1kPZmKQ9hkPA0D0Uo8DiVjYCF4lGmk/KkCOnr6GS@YvVRKIgKFMTb@rskS4IZD@OngT4Zv3iDj5jiaIYX1hjofDw4EQObQDmBV9JwZggdezTbDTmQqjo@dNh/j7eFr/@GBZI6otj4@Oth/WqFourp3BgKV0kHYjOeDOKG7LRXaUW/YMqV5MMAzwWRMUoKzIRh5xzCY4jACUwyeiEhfabAF2IDR4pSA6jCl15/OgteF9O5N5YGQkDuFXCa8GUGSOPjcNIVRHkB3tXf8cGrSr38GwhQzvB5OfiguzwBYM2vcsUWfGLBD3XOsVokd0ojTBukaaAuE61Y4s2E7toIdQTA4daIR8ekdgCA3FDVRjLKmYBBx2xrBAD@Gs0Mo@@EADEgIGBgUmA1DbVN9TsxNZsAkcf4NRmLzhkJPuBSpGt6kdcJoB4yDnm4AC59GdyqzU0AIHCiTme@TLF9DDCOjqYERzUrclEeQIw3dxvJrWTTqHlpeF4sXBlLYBbptKFUccuNYkkrtkBkg4negpM2RJfoiaOHHGOQT3UskcSy6ywdZSGU4QMBEBXORJL07hjF0TRgooC@f/GH79rnlOjYWsroPqIEVlbEOZpDPK14go93dw9yDxeU7DzmU2DVnLVK2UayzhWt40Lpsp@d0HLYGAEiaqsoJ@9DGOVvotH19AC3KekMFtNtx7PEMDZpmOAtcWEeS5zNTCJkhePUV9AJsfqYnAAvyfHz45T701lo@m4X0B7YsPWEmI1hm84iOBpsAiHWNHtIN1uSX5qA7dqfIyXPELJBPU6HUMPm8nA7yM6RKtPA3FDTayLkLtPPAqxWY5uV9nwZEOBU5GC/I/ZTwwZsN5DA244yuQVFMIb1W4ZP6RcZ1mpniW0HVnSvtvuPrmc9VYNH4knB4oFhM9jLxlXhGUfAtkxfLVVmmZZ5nkEtNMI/2caZmDu6RaRoZ9MXOjQWGucUTeC4omlN4bHpBNvk3KIMw5Gz@O6kUMnZKXRg3TzR08ifdoSmZRtdh8imMr6I5k6GD6FotU4GSB@kXB2VhMLHGJfnOEMa0LbNn9S3/kFYhejYO3FRi3ipyLeG7B/xmguCJZcJohM@2TDoZXCmY9FF2h8M/BU5OWD2fqbxIXbOVWZtge@Q4bhentjSaUMmFRd8XHhnHG7RUfwQIeKh96t@9oJ9/fPRgv/Fk9@STSmbouZme1QQe0TIbfRjJ96A5LHgwbTjfuQ@0Y9lO34IcBSjfnPWeOo7PhQdcCrndE8OAAY6HDxoPD@8/3X36dZE46tGt/rCnYxpLqzMAIY5jglmKxnCaDsgW9nAhJhAuju4fPQywfPrs4eFu48H@k6OTCJpXw56la6PM4KyzKEOfIgjT1Cwv@qNea3qNisboU1MogtnggLPMYGDOFAXeCrrxSHFIqqIHisjYPSoKzmnrOGvvspyW3dpqNfVi0Sy0jI2NzbbebrU2clox3y7mc/ksvDYLWyZ7S@CKYo5o2gpMfEoIZ88wDkg8fTR1I5BwYBxugMQynpuu0HdJ4ox83tzc2NK3jK2tLT232VrXc8VN0yxstjeyWbOgZdvNolZcX5q4SDJQtJrY@jT9Ba0OZ0rIE5hfAj5TzYEnHmS9C9bK5XIFI9/eWs@18tmNVnMrmy@2mtqm3twys@2NdS2ntYycVgrCAo8FxpDpQoWhVGmDaBp4KRp4JqWgM41WMa2bBgvrguGsriOLGQQL4zhwEB4b6DEUy@KAM3DPo3uwKI7zU8K9gO59XBKfSLJkDR0FYJEAcWVcdZuB4xY6hmviU6vFwCoF/5znvziQwHypZa8Q@QWuqkfyd6lp5H7ut9tTzjlyPlOwK@tNnNfJma@pT69mi8xe85oLHOLbIHx8LX4uvmtec4FDfHmOD9fw56Ob8ZkHGiIrEDJc85@La8ZjDmCIaZMwRfcJTPyK5Ldok4CIa673wkAh7i3Czdf/G6@8BoraDbH8j9TMG8gJSGIPHZCfH1q4aNGeajFSOAI/leRgGmF6Fg19uOySOZ8Z2SnncjQcb/uWfebQODk0NbKqlsf2HIbun/Wuh2zDyIJeU6BhGgI5ZkHqvH6zTa85ANjHzs5CkgdN8YqeHnpWPfOUPjjZOy8F09PWU9E3zfYQBj2ZpmWj@QYwZatIkO1m01oECiWBuyeC7xywEns6hIFnTt1QtWCUi8tEwKL5nPPJ4REBNnUas02vdbCpwveHrg@hxPe/fqMFlXC9irr6mIZ@oaFhmxdYXUp7YY2JoGih1/zanXTyVDBkugmloeN6sd4LDfNRU@0rSld3@zjCEtUNBIovoIQltMZTzqdegu/8SEqMCnl6TYXZVp8Z1/bS@I7DPBg2T@pmZiWIx0vDa1yEpRLhg2DLpEAu1juvEXPEh4MRUQf6nDkpnE1fsGDDJlse/O7QH/I37nK4qUatAf6WtVYBmc3rTc0E4VhvWuaS@nf1s2HLUUDGoyxjwgpzYCe5p2k6pd3Tz7ixgcb52ecZdK1OByQJ8V0EdtGFUQ0NRzMX9LmJRDx76A2UJlSWD22IbNQq@kticHv8vQjEEnsBQ8PiUrN69LpFpYfEReQCwhwVNG7PUiKFZs0Uc09vjnGQ3v1wKsMISbQB9lMxUqnsOnZ44ZJ3dEvV4vDYS1L4ra35ofnGMF4k8wZWGb4hTOFTx5RnsUXshoqFPszq6z0l14oYFzL3YNJ4YpoDSjM2itHTPSAtX1SHeQ7VR69l5I6dlAEDLndiWkLsk@QEOx8WLaILDiZateH0LA@bdm8RM51dd5zEiVvz6BWZjLbmFWyLpCWvq4Sm@XzBMXxcwV5AaLfgcnzxGJfnI5SjOosKzXAu8LdQyug65yZ/z@/z3sxN1S04ltIjkrCMuZ1L63ovAk68i6d5Vg@EfyAmmm3VaKjLd2sE2xPyhcHr67WAe6HoNb/wz@Zmxjd6c92nG04wIxIdz92yMXhWz/HYMb2XlSVkzPP4e34ziBa7pdsKLR9FzfODiUQNmComZRcQg97rOL1CsZPR4bWQYoZuGzsS8b0tywxZnqbdzPIC@cqxNfFd2FecZdyzm@qOVjJc3OAQMS7ptufxPbGGuTiDQKK4a2l@5g6yRQqpZvjwelEFuEb3Qh8H35@jO1pUukF3NBiTvA7iIwbYKoLBd7kM//PEtrE8ttbteNo1tJs3ZSJSuWc9E3o/el@rUpbLah8YQstmb8/h2r2hOTTnMrij5isTN/gvGcXcPlFZkY1VMTmKE0g4NRpCvRHjz1ulGjt@tC1lMMBsoZHfKB7N5XcDEOwHOEJ/AoYnaLgesGMPB1OVOzUKtJ8uL7nuIGjZTmsqkejzoRypeLMQNiX9eyb9lg7O@GASl8IqG9lsVghFkenuKcuyQdt6GPaVxd9TEZPLJOYJLPacbsQ4P47JzCtUvXXmKTgHejvulFs0o0DAW1sZ27JNf4zvWzLapuP0PqT2gN@2LJT3QIrFJaKbavGaLCU2zbHJtImHky7N9qIJE94XidEsFByO2ZcRQnSS9lY1rKBwAw20M2NdPoUUmfK9KRbo4Wleim@y6C0WVMVkjKYW1c2ljZGLv07T7On8MypsLMO3pa4vxRdKK0KuplUwXDnja2WTtdfYDMsajKGwrBYMirpm3yTrktGE3no19ILPQqCRg7853iqtTC4KN7CAR9j4nlqXi0hRvmPDMM7X3Y6J46Aerp8L10V8OZh/n1u4h329Y/IzZcsY52RqBHdY89HjxDh/kqTE96cZEIxvEllOCtCYzsyxF3znInw0NqA@h/2bZ/lm2r1BW5puauhqZu6yww1iot11unbX7PI9Q6FtUfMAivT5acBlmYD0d7oGI/4U3c8ULdme0@vdpmSRP3Ju6TjtuWnaxzNqLQj6QXjHehM8xOfG2UPo5qmAqL9f1G665hB6K8/xnYGpkG0RaA8nl/h7ERcNloF@3lmrpTMKUCLB9@fFb9wUsKM7/mBAn8agN/ToRUEVOlq4ZMjGp84pSqJL5rgd9Y3Tb6rCUT3g30dQ4QuYTRPPueAWJk7ZZsdpGl3rpkQ3Td23rbNMMMfErUuHvYNIOVlMeYDOas@C4nXHKtJLJep/jJ/DRZUupqt4xxYa5lNBie0NXXeMlB7MRdOUAW3JmpxZnnCV6f0Z4WQxX@5Aw6JUiZXHOd4kQ@DOvWCH2pI1F7FQuZAsSWpHCV0xsyDmaAvnraa2j0ba1Po6fy2SpmbyT4mKrA9/yMSr2FZBU5BWZH4Y3Kdoamqxe24XZ3eHHe86k@TLAi0QzPA1t/Z3O3gK/BaVzysa@jLdFp9FdZDrZXC/PHwbUJtDc@kST37pGg/BaT1Fdyz4NOAD9TpcOGHXswYefzOlnZsrelxftr4ONZ4/9hZ11jLbfBUGTTfJjH3HxVNbIJwohmt6Bk7iI2/nkhjnY7bTAR6v9NgEOICdm4XrK@VzSSLsO5UvHpsdHbd0PrRwd2dvDqUA1tkF85uQfm2oe9bXho5vzsU3u2h@E7pHescyPpkq@QBZUKJi3x//TDUFdLpe@Bddy6MDM4FhycQVEhknW6SzBowc5g35ZhYKwuPly@dmIiKX2G/OlEMW7EsPDbhUgf763LjmrQE4Axp8jsm0bPrf8ml6V3znUtX8jQfLor8Y9gdDT3zmx057g6KT4/0zcvcuLGCVymvg0Kyr9/z5E@iR6V2Q3kRnOjEukue/tHpOh31ZzDIQ9kB4Q/F@DsHdh279ie5Di7DnEDDFvYCXzy7R4syJwrmk9xpowlxnimVb/vJZIt/XYbQVfDEzvAPCY5@Zh/hW730oBuVkfok8XCrJggwwNnqoVoDvu/NY0zWhC@XKDMItcss7MwNo8ZgO/6Mx1D8QpX4RmbkXrFaIfsc2L6Ljv6WLTiXsbB176Ct4vmDpcvqkkyks7WRKbFQsRGiFJb62/@hZMkoytAf3JhHXhDHm0OuNJ6aF2yFmKNGyQcpbzJynoYOBygOTtEQ8pd2iN4TZHeD5NeoDHjjzBlNPxq7p33o0Bj3KsP/ANHAR9Ma4HzuPQL6Dvm0AXLj/1OTH06aYy/yAGOyhY@g9KJ/WjdEcE9o5ncdk3K4PzCbUb29imi@wzUP8QPf1BQIWTUfS4DI03UgrVq9puq9onjFiXjRenk7QJ@aIBi6LCYY3SMU3DC6V44zfVHOZXTHyBo5j8zdx5Sx8tEfLuQ/0F/S6/eK/ipuop7rDueO/6dweheoH@NHJRdl1zabT42/MwoKe0Lb4PgfdtUwv89CyhyNyK2wwBcS5@SMkvps4q26SChhoSMESa7jNGHfNCd45MwwDOflc92gHwvzBz9SW5tvvd@rqruHgqpwwfOCaXORs2g1sPdyzzXdKNKFiRsDUdGMoTjndlNRev9mn18LBS6S2n5pNPPvXpLOpvj6aJ1lOn2ETjjOnyAK2ho2/wBJPYHiUvHnGbHZsN13i1oBexNQv5hJKEN1jyzTe6MlbjasiLYqmrDM6DYHnNqrpbXogA/VMxe/ips@Mv2wuPTgfPGdBZtg3cQ18eiVoISk5XpfowJm/6h@yWtcUO8dx1yI0@sCM/FbZXUioiB7@j@5/moEuuVHYQO0Jw5HSAUZ28z4DSPzQtcXnNsT2xPH8tjU6GqBeLMddxFkwW3kIAh/eCNC0tigTUHv2sMenQzqRbWX9Fg31QDBsO2DqEfP2TcW0zxXSFzW6niPHJZU3mV1UuOabLUVMkOCyhvIwkMtCMPGds5YbZZO4q1XL8IIdFTbEPtd5hXvhhauS4KEMPPpmBt6Tw4dHJ@rA0@a2gmAaE3crDq0erjJSgwvcoGDIdE166@nUOHbJk3QPTZ17yxWzkRmzV7obWa7lO/TwXGLm/rGm7D08VBFgQR3xJRcFPricOPVZvMFj0NWbpq9n9IXDLPQ1/fki5icnjx6mJue0WWKv6zp9Mxn13js@TgOHYp8ez/WOhj6AFtV2RguDH@5rWnIOyT@zaUlzEXOdE9MiTCcmDJahwj7hR4ZvFM8MZ2C2TsYD83Poe5HBe7eMvrAwk4/1c6uDLZdtLSwoatxsSy1sJCPb100X1ZMF30X1eWYNkMMa9Mnwz8LdNCh4rGfc9fnCx7INC7NCEMuKjRQfFkjLXqdW31KgZXS6aMro3i@aME3TFpXzsd6GemX5hZU1DTBPMOk557dY7jbF8EcJnRQfqEqxbtxnv6n0gd1n8IWrB8IRjM2Fu3iWIQidC3Mb/IVpj3Vb4XoElg6@B9ibLgf50rzFelm4QemcbRXnL0aGRw5YwiBj8oaIT9xIkL29@4c3BXgqynIJlDhiSbrtQqVJwOr54V9ws1yhXcVTA0WN4qQ0yZvBhAQ46oYxxDl04AEqI8BEQk@lkklJhPoEJK8@aoHDQB4d@IdWXWbZwIip7EJ3SvCo7yXBVnW2XQGIZLLMFSdBtwBd5NAss7YVIIYu2erYkIAgflJih90XV17isR50RgHWWo2tXo5K2ZJ2hbpUSjKr13l68aFI9kcD0kD3lAevrer1ympcUeKr8VO7xLLxENzseeZ8cH0KFhKLH5HgsHS5dkqHVEuGZVnm@r5AikbleF3dbgGrE50F5N/lWqu4SrQTPBfy57/XEjoDSTdm3/L0HhQIqv6EfqvrXOzweIPiGgx0lxTAkVaqHleYpeztClVyXFUgVNazg5Oi0Fcm9IyC5QlfZAlTwekG94eg@gGfkwVPTXiUXEQchgoyZTi9Yd@G8VvL73oqO7ZIs8DQnZwVFNpXbd/FReBWmh2ylon77klhBO156DnOWSjR//nvcS1tpDZCHOcPoid1i5EYUTuERqrRDMMZQqoDJG9M1xEgCSxk3fCHuLmItH2SexKVKZD6OKB1JVCeRtFwDWp7u8dM2Wdx1AGEKnzKVjuxuvv0489r2XrlHetnzP/6jUzyUhSc/BFwLk9OswCkfIWEFfXOg/fEN87k1ZHMIwx1alhi0uiC1wfqQOVEhmo1AhpznEHQbHAWghQ4htQo9Cgl0Ez1HGxT7pNOQyJY84K0qNHhbRtFXFLG6kEDA2uSUPNWV1lNDPmmF@XYZ3mIEDXR6VynoYM6TK2@iRrBMMjqiL1lJGtCR6fls2DjBdlDJXT9Ssgt16Pn5DIPzOaQToyc59RcvkLZWW1UtqtkgsGOg9oday9OR7mscjra3K9nvKBQT09HH2VzX0CpOy6EupvBlrf/@MHlqlrNvn3r6WMmy1fxMj/XB2xi9fLJ4ZP945Pdk2fHUAtXAWM74Kd7A16DVEQH9rtOj/RmQrngDMcH8J/QNmGCqJ05mZSiR6sJVJS1rMir3BhhTVOhbwg@L7xnRvyvAwieBh2wFPYLQAU6ERuWGmaea8dkIqxQeEhUZvk0yHDVsGDw9OQcXkpFJbMKFJYChXXLomKLM7vD3W5TYjdiWV5sO3NBsMTC@GqhP8/i3CK4@gfJ90D3vF883xzL8nwTzJJ8A2joGoQ52D18@Ozp/nSwoJMnrlvZygudApw5Y0vjcyWBhkdS5SMC4qahisxkCsCtojPjiqNN/8KEbAnmaPR5YKJQSr8sTQgTSqaC@svrQgpJJCgFKN2gIDKr8qBtjSJJDProCLpLnsWQCRzIIeog4aosMMdID7eKT5ANxCqKK2h6T4iJC34d96LiTzpocZg17KOHHm9zC7qqsNfxGPxHeqXAlKuzERPdmVZnCsvBr2faHchwAJss8z6KrfKCkFd52uUwvag7GdLUeqXT6jrNGghVAdBL9/SBF4iCMfbY8c0Sez10SB1RwExC@YLUdutc3TlVLVfgTWqOYHANgm/QbxG@w4PjCkpnXDQj/h6luaGNHRUAca3jQmGI76KGfq7Jgav/5UXuCMW0QVdJk9GeUEQZSgkeO7c8C0baVAltlHF6wCkxNyLjqL2eFFGx3Z4HMkkLum@QUHzsakE4Uel8OT9krthMjgFNqqHImGayhLBe5bqiUuhKL3Do/5IHXiU4wuxFcMa3VxQFSq5j2YGq@hLqrqd52BLz3SHuB6/GrwUJklAik9L1@70I4BwdzKdm5v2v/5DrXT71wfwdYR5l74PtV4WtDeZfC3w0DWz/LLTlwPZdbnuRwSq7rpt2ks6JkuOFR/KBOu/JUmw2a8gaArX9lKWw0rHCPz98wjwDVTVjlfb1UaS2kNEEIxVm9YE2zqmqEZzHMKnJCZ5E7XOgFCAvIBOUclCwofhMt55ARaWlTAZTjsvuKm3NN0d8RxzpLX09RAXcIItlCvnChpaBRCrnAULSJtbB48UcYTJZAtYonVuDysumwba3t5nsGXrPrBTKnEQyq/qLdfllmNBVgJX4eKHGIAwEmYQAv6oIlljVU1oSg2J/FtfiyNpaDqc4EAoTZACQJDrbgf4hkDodUVRAzrY58klwGgfjIODbthNRjR0gUgARx82VSk@3ysmRYVwWirRTNVoN8nMEO0awkjyPZmsv2Kl/ateFunAG9PejORRsg/mfzNEhzukQ9atd13WdmNVUjblh945tB1fYDiC1LJHL5NYzWiEZaXyyQAXpxRb/FlBCGweeYZjWK2fg7e7tH3569OT4mto/gozPgsVZvLqdOlXUdK0eGuJhuqcL9f5B5vjR/YOgKKOpmswNIcTkPMRsMufFNpvSBbE/56ezr8dNHtci0rK3RUybjZUDOlJ0HfvENxMB3OOHQ6/FmkheXtXq29VTO3Yt@rfzFNPH1DUkLjCdeqSWPj6bTExieBHNCV5E46mB0hENNY7ggXTfOZvoLxEOEQ8OHmABDiCpmQBqEfuEBBzxGaCJoq0cvwnHI9bHZ4lIu3iYogjkSXBnDjatiV5YoRC1q3vdntWUoAtvoYZkrs4s0NcVKkJTvUHP8hNJSejQBWEC9deKm3NGpZFKe3USSWzmhCvNlulYDfAlJWgEgC/@ZOh12RNnEJnbemAGpqcgj7AHQ75vw2SfDvsA16bPU5MmrkFCUSAwFFQ8TCofV0PLEipWRylUYwvx1VDRqsi42m/lE6Ok2jVHLasDDDyRTENL/0gDwSpUAoOZJrWrdhx4HC/hj/F8bbRIP0jT7miCXK/pqmW3zFECVceV6iChonv84vl5HFjqLA2Qut@9QEHojN7foCHqvmgRE525M41tK7wuZ0Z/8tYWqt/r4zbwCoMYj333IRihf0q0@/qAJYakjdtjKiNr4jRhpz3fTTKlynVa2SyVonE1fMgD5GYEbZOJCIclcB4ykalA7aCrZ7fw88YasJqmqnUwUyRJtopzanvQleNsVFKCcRIEKRHaCtYtK2GKOPWqnPIgDPpLpCGToUrqOd6kR5nWZBwsC8o1q96NaBactEBeqltbJVEb06xmiwFZXOfyagbQzmEhgZwK5SuUlECp4a0peL0OLg8DW7j3mWnbJhQQ0Exfhz5YHwKRucl0cFVWenLLBhexeBI/EVpPIKHTt2/sxy97uHtoNVOm6ZnyFfSpL0@xU22LbnWc@e8zaqZ8mVjtVcYZEHSS1cRqt6Kl1tdSqVV7LbFqY1d/9y7O6lytgiTRUGGQNAIgZbWXLAM9g@RRWbXLq/p2YrVVya1RCLDCMO0SArzzMurlqn6VWb0LPXUaXFzeeBOrHqk8zqqqdgXpwxaymkkDzVyihli6JwujX7VSKUyDutrABLzLnB6niGefHmdoAqks5NFMpy@a2wxXDWvi2i1hvACFs6hoYOw5ZOzi8FgjAEYlUsHOgTl@C2QPHvFnuKDEaO3a9KIDAHna5/aMRfC7OGmj5Aqmuc5pKMBRAgoRrWk9mQRm8rOfxbQCkxOrO4X13nkqns@W4aWV8yzPPlo9VZTcai3GYvdW67ruN2Donlm7PH1Q7Jwzs50rvK5ZbfV1sfIkfVZ/8uSLd413L5Ly6Fwenybisb2jt7K2AUE22Rb9bvVsstyC55b6GmNrGSmWWdPubmYyL1@@BKEXn1pVrQYgav3du2QtXq9tYp4WIYoncrnksWVZGXY68Fot@DldVqab6@ox/qRSCYXRVXaxmFLjbjs7/VEbDaNds9MZ7utj7m7Fhvg58EXYR18@f/4cDc/pYW@ecncW4xiZgCs19HyM5bK5P//JylX68klj@8@/2c@YK/g5ws93rh6h@VjLf7Sy8tH9@xsbaSgtbn7y5ZOv7@7ubjxI55/U8jsbSnZl@8/@dGUll9vOZVbqnqfV47WzL@RcdkNW//zH8caTJ1/zPKwtfNaZBkZ8F@GnsXyenbE38Jy1Gf6T@U0rYtbR3Gy/YbE3MU3TYmP6a@BKAw6tK8R8pp8VplV3Nv/b945ex/xYNZd57sLXj72OFYoxbgQD2NYD23msGttGsMJVbJypVCpg3Pxv/xbCVz8FPOgz3oZXNR/gKoxjVaVCQd7GqgUwaLkcxPt/f@Mb02m5V4NH3tjMyTt1eNbo2ZZi1RF4VquHByxXza0JQtKKd7W7aLD9rm86@LFMdhrTihtH98jVNvEeMBirImp1Uy2qOZbRtNwpjAGYqGxR6TinEuP0i9YulB7UOnMibiFVCBeAfx4jCgISIiriZuFAhMUdns/CPT/V9bXN1Ebunl1@Lp7Q8Mt7nuLVi4WVey8fZDLbVZAG8CmV7p0GjTDDNouy49zDKUI2wkIvs4dh7VTlbDEnp9Ppewg/UvAZxSYlyHghsdhU0cbYxMaiTjEWBGMTmA@F28fnL/79X3z/L75Hf9@n33@SYsH@P6V2Xq8GD9CQXHXly1NhHU09wKTqT5mW/fhtPL8ePwYTNCEt9J3kKBarVvFF/8JGJvrOuAmfamghiEmQ@XBMMKKgUGNS7F0mw7BK2HmQnXsrpZViqVDKZRpsJif3oJrk3OaWXK/m8rkjqDpNporbikAB9h14VuCP/uEJrfheIRfhTCDXnxVWvfUzy@KlWC1Wq9d5465Ga@mm56mqlIH6VLI0ojmPnUsxBZhaKvUUiJsJIofnNHXj8yylqg1hRoMDX0dRHMAqxX4JT1VisUt46u/Wau/WgphrVWHYVurVlEgQfNTGvXpKubqqqS9S5bL4B8mxHNrwgQ@DH2SkfqUo2y8AWW0abXzDiRece4idI6e32nixDehT27XtirNHP7WBpavUX1Rr29MoROLu3UupUAv3AEF1tc6SIJYqykptYR4AYT3BYGgDdXy1fVW9qm1fXW1vw/82va/EF1yvtq/902fyLICZ@NeRqk5rmeppRrT3ah3saqaKLmrmFAxV@AIc9DpS7BIJktXqCg61KkpNK@TrJF2wR@wRf2wb/uEXWNEFHR6hm81fNocIYEJn7iLF1oDNZkraWm49kx99VNjPAa/yMOqcLGfW0PAW@36Q17akGI6DtvhwaIscXr7/6n/H3@n7r/4ArJBPvMGWfJuv8e/hG/x77ePfiYF/T1/jHzt5g39Pffx71MS/Jx7@nbzGv90m/p308e/@a/x75OPfsw7@SbEKYyCjru5ke9nzrHamnYHBYlkYInSzXa0FfJJlTZYdZ8cs23e0FphM@MuCycq2WbbDsnbW1jTwBIPPsj6a2vDpwF8bsLjwZ2WziDx7ziCWHnJf0vFP37cNljyVaiz@0gSxUtXUrFqwGnXUFwayZDmWOT3NcGmb5TbKpGvs6oo1GvuPHzQaGWy/p4@co8n/0VE/al363z9yHh05fQf@j46OHp0CJ66m7qWUe/BUqqlt8dmJVcs7pyUF6T1oWrHM9s5pdV1BcyEFrSWHbqkPfCYY4VtdOZXiF9CfX5RJbChfnJcvymQIrdzQEAACjBsgVFmIG@AC4U6fZ0g8uIDnnPCSDY0X4BmYuCHz/OIUxWUYIIX/UBxR6z/Av/X/rf9Hz1iiVk9CG7i82k7Qk8S/ZPLy6vJKvKvJREJYEtvwhw5gxyCXV1U0EtAlmGqJZD15dcXd4J1IbnOEVYxju0qBJ4DAmWJhnBQvfyX@Yb8Yt3hO42XG9MpqQix9np6OstlkuQku4eqH/pZW0ZJl2l@02qxp9T/7Mc6iaDtJAspvlMvaGjfnNnLl8oawbBbL5aIwryYSW9efanZHK4Bgs7GRTJbLYNkJcGbBGuAsAk5hzgNK09ONMrb7ciyJ6efMIJHFKVm64Ckul@S7dxPiPrSdwSB59662lX37NnRqNFqW22ig@/rbt3JDxt1Jla082LPFt2@BD8WTjpt47PB18YSisY9yVYphy3Ehl5vgzbRMbhJnV/d033cTb6xBWsZ99Z6cpEsZslnHPY3/9Lvf/OZpvIL7Vch1Q0MEGAvLb28XNqrVwgaYC0UoCHmVb4BKdFJbWvJqNSPz7DJ5NR4TXlpxM0muV3H0Z7FttlOFxuvhwy6vYlSlbCOfTDTHZvISXAI3bWuLO7KNQqKY2hJ/lZUkq64x8YcjtPXUxtrm2j0coo3mP8huy5d6JZ7JxK8ql3oJJ/Cuyoa4AgiPwOp3765vQZEWs@VTqdF4sHuy28C7kHGDAvTDDB2Jd0u4@Dxw4zWabc1v1WuYvfppPF4q36PK14p5FouXBZwSh26AFbd4HxDzPMlq42H4EaGd@a3FBkzbXIdeGTplaUCbxTazrIXr7S5z2u0VcIQqZE3cGuGZvV5wb9KF4/ZaF1bLXJFiTx7u7u2fpHPbIC/kDnb30rnjZ/djGlrzEzt5r6P96f7ug6NnEODJw/3d4/2PDz/ff/YE3D3plftGN03dHJpm42I4vHjNXllWw4LS6w0ty3IMFxLRME1zAGDBUzZNZhqWp796pbsDehhn5O9/9O33P/of3v/Od9//zrff/873f/rV978Nv9@D33f597v/ZiuP759@9c9@9/1v/w44/if4/TH8fvLTr37zG/xH9j@B33@JuP2J@EXg@E8CXL/606@@9@OffvVrP4DfvxS/H1z//fpP5v@@/63FPwz3vd9dDvPdfwu/3@e4Atjv/jZ3w@81@N/mcL/2g/e/8e/4/5@JPzT@zvvf@BN8Ccs//cGf/Zf33/wPuVzxz/71@29/9/23vvf@W998/63vvP/WP869/81/rWWjr999//0//Os/@v2//qP/hf5/j96/f5v/9z/4p3/5f/zlf/zLPxK/n8Dv34HpJ3/5H4B0/@4Pf4T/3/vDv/vjH@H///av/u4P/8Xf/er/SoYfcsP/8y//DX//za//57/9re/89U@@8bf/4id/@8M//Ov/89f@r9/8z3/zP/7B3/zP30THH/7kr//4V//qm9/@q2/987/65lcL3t9e@v7qFu5f/RJcbp/O2@C5Tb4@1OWrnys9v0hpTGIBOqGLj1gOROL7Y5OVpSzLMv6Cdvr9f/L@N38FyP83ABBs/xPY4J9bwOs7ZGFffIG8MerPUjT5o6S@@AL9xXD@C7DFqjRnh71EMVdMrYGUvLa1FU7mbU/QfAdCvM2AbJ@99xZQfEHh@cO@CMAgbb9FYADHBFgAN51IgsFdstz9p1/98x@TRxgWnX9lCmU2cI5CryL426A4voO8YZLdKPR3kL28/9E33v/4H7//0Q/f/@hXsT9RNrbSu2mQCpbPkQNg/hZwCFi4DRwAajjmZStsRcqBYWUbZ3YlLfXyJaR@BUwwgFuT8utgk7QqmTU0Q8AU2Bif8EvhG/6ljS2GFnAZkSt8WQq87qdYpVJJSaMKTg8iKFgxzIhVizgHhfMtFcCLgXiYdKMIYyM2uk9YIGQl9ZQ11iojHjCFDlXCgHQlodNTWcvJqWLlAURYGT1giAuRp6SX8H1ZqRYroyqie0dJAByp@xAlQFUwdaPqO7BXCCfAS6MH7yApxUoqVS2CSwUzmaLY0g2KU8tT5ijvKZYSU5/wxd2qO/cY@0jWijKfJIWiZAIa36kJNAICOPifptZEdug/MNJvDcNDPY2ofLgb999BZwovAACvouAmR/gpCqbmHniPOKoURQufFMcAJZfiM2AsdCAhJyWlqH5TZIH4IQ0f/ADK7arEM7S6uiqhVV6XG0cwKIXRn3tW8nzdxUVYkkJLTC5syeiMO8aCDOLWwtUnNIZde7AGbw3@91doHzjlqbwmrcZx9iXORKwfpfjv3r019hGUAX0nbhJTUuvOhhPj2d1OpeQcRFx1wLZGWU0RIpy/oP@U9CImsRjRADSaNH/DR62QO4PhvUgvObyoSJiy3LqGdpyNHQ6HGEJV02o6Lb4qfclBFQaVfMVXXSVpk5@q7eEZkWCeYkviIyymFTbogBBdRZlkSSlmmCjGMemR17nvjGAYk5bltFbAZbykmDI6KeWwFUv7pSy8v@6USpV32samBF@yD/FKTHFIFeipa7qmur2NdFG9VGiSDI0g/xakalXsZ2CaVD3ePwHwkyOm5bIqgyHQ5cZmbiO/kc@tFwr5zZy2UdjaKOSL68BxC9l8LqdtbWxsFbc2r2b5Ep@GLhbkRkob52AwIhc2cR76H117/rt/NO@Z74qPVP2CjVRcoVCupGqvwnfbruJ@B/k0K5dpEo/KdrWWTeNfbn0d3pD2tJbfrK@s9C4VLIpT2uJ5iTtKIPnSpcJg6HgHHibdkdgdcIIH4sAVXyb26BwelcV@DLzqm@/JkLU8kDzUzSnQPEcnDaJPeco2AJK4vLyM/KTYypdf@qxahVGPcnggxaAxd1mwPUGxWmpXpQupW0PXJN8OYy3rcwtv3VFbljfo6WMg1awqxa6urtrhghlZeYgWvq8McmmC@WqkS///88t7cjklt66sa4q2jv83GHL4f3v4HPzn8A2h1nPSNlc8VcWLaR29VQkvb2eJ5GWr0nIMOkFWbldqdRWP7JdbatNpjVXPH8OYXBBQJd7sOcZZPPC08EY7PC9byegZtdEACvQdGKjT0H4nt5kvrWTcjIq76xNtltzJFTbB5dQOnMAljy4vpp22Si01SNEjaCsQLlfKFfJX20IvZRXyg@mqYiouReJKtmObV7ijuqS3gZleGnwfUknO5YtyuVae2DcLcrl@da9vtiydnWbxAN/l3ICFgnwVwEHUOMzHiRiW6OMtVLhVv5Q9zSYXBM5CYEgypVTaFsquqrSzpAZcsY538dbq24EarKr07t27EW3mKh3avtjVldsoojuTcF7hLshedzVuzBcmxiwaT1Bl2WOoO@DlNnuIxzN8h504/BjAfdNYALHX1elq4j3X8bxfAOa@bp9xrwcWV5UUen2i4w0MXt/yuwsgng36eOLWdH9pGPb7TUgg0hQHuA8vt@c48wA22bMnC3L5KFR1iBvASNchgD89/PiTk8j3ZH937xOpwO4fPX4w88kLoDx7uH9wElo3uW8QNB@i@Pr@w4ezVvEBwaFMM2ArLL@JG8ADi8Z0X78ox4plWa6xUR1Kxr8CSbvcsodb2t272hMXT1kU2Ea1mC2VTrPlK8hS5f5ZaYBbyT1zsObtj7Y2IItsyJ5BoeuuIcvQCg9297DRpTKVeAtX3WH4w1b/5rd@z1yz12S5zHDDklyQHuHO8y2NH6S0PIlOM@P1t3jVtS@hNqWWc2HTGdFmb2iy4YAtdIQPOqHRtTpdn/kXTgAgNXWdwe9DHwhvRh9/uYPP4yC3az69OeC40clqs6ykkjCX2yrmi1vruWK6uFXcyGuFfD6t5dLaZnFzC@SOrFbUCsX8lpYubmytb4DABL75rU0pBvKC1c5kQErVZBm@JUBrG3iF2zbeheeo3aoU4zPU7E1CT7KYHtqHTDYhjIx3B3s@Ha9ZsypybgPPvoHUChh1ZrDYwcFe9uBAlu@jBdfU9rKy3EJLvpjNbt6XZZN89kCoy8myw8MUUdmD7HNLNnt/T5aHHAHqYpTlLlr2CziUlmULLXu7BwcYTxstOQwPYGfch1t6gWUTwGy0rK/TWFyWX4foAG6XR7RBKd1HC8aJPgfcZw/8ZPnjID3ZLGB4yuE4hk@CvO7uyvIht@zuos8eZTzPk/oZWnbpkWUXLECEstwBQwd7A1lughFJUZYNMBljHdzwujxUx2f7uiyPeQFhEcnyiKB140yGEaNwx2g@@eQTveu3zA5/xi7/QpM7BB9rNNw/aH78cbPTabrj3f2Pn6LP3t4nens8dJudpgjWbMDjQBjwOeuPZx9I42Gjoffm@nwGPvaMT2PcMDFtDf01pEk8HYyk39gDnz3wmTfBz7HB0wfQJj73@/C9rzfJJ3jIh76jZlMuI6GiPgycjsc2c2YDL0j3dcN1ymgfVVZYPBFPj2uFbL1M7qyfYMlLYF7o307QDew4ygJJ@3JcG1Wy9cqospkTZ/QS8ukol7fk9Ep/R9sC2UTf0XIbqVEJb@xw2nEWV7SdhHZ37U3iMYgh6xsl@XRnR5FrWn0npxVLhc0Xa0NZTpbwvbO@WXoDA684jK7wlaxt1ndA4JkE2dxM6ZlcaXMTB2XlKygRHzqk5tA3G41E4sLUz5JJTDF28yCEUXbZmLJqlduJUXpU4QljYwg/qmhlrh@KZa8ha6FqwiHedsxRdhJYAqOdbAmXRRKytlWUIQmZTCKZRMaErAS@L58H67nhJ2KYMvJHZSWFX5auFQtJFY98NZx2gy6MZS@jkJOtFtJzPKdJOhqCzdQ0HeCVpBMcdGKPQMKV1QQuwzVujKQR10DG@AyltrklSVUxvnrCb7AsC@vHn@ypMOQSNlR2qB6gcOu46h6yvSkfrogvcDqBvk79xMQt0kbgtse1J6j7Ixhjo4QceARKq1ShNkg9@aR8qTRwKeVrJ2cnJ18oV1G0xzDW5AnBM2Zl0iaC@hpQNaTVYnqlCiYdRUlKJRRB8oKKo1GtVhqVvtkf@GPIcxDuM0aaEyeIDj2emfDsGwW/xBOhwqNRyV5N4B8P@@w@B6Jjo0GwRuU@lG@2bKOmZROtq2wUG0nVFuqNvF@5fzksoTh6VTYrpus6rhzDs7Y7dmVoe3rbfGK6eMzz8GiVtZmJByqN7svTfYTcQ7n6Sqm6zJ5KR0JXqs3ktFPEikWX@FpYIpd0TAFX/65geJJ4kSy/Bpu7yhIt9X5yZ6PcStxnjSS4ZF@2X7ZZjhU2ynQ5UQIxAUegksMS0ZOV6meAmOM9K5UgIYIkzgAnRrQKNWK1yEdPDqyrcqdSQ@i3@NpWZLmuKLW3dalalqrAYMrjmF7xhk1@63i2qeWyhfII3LTNjXKXNSvNF6OyWxnAqJyVe1DtYiqCn73QcR8@FBLgefOWJd7/yjeS20q@wh3LhOxtD4SJhtqojCY1tF6p5TYK6VxhA2cuCuvw09K59RxuLU7nslvpnAYyBcgaEB5@m2DfgB/AgMiR03B@I9FLyIzJ6ewoq2ppzdTSiexLq/UymT7DmSaQCanQkmnf2beBcsABCQjIlqzw1ZOp3Fov0XKYvq0QDQPTK1NG9XSXDax0F9E8NfUeB08qbH0t0VtNIMzqyXCwX6uXSvujwdfQK6G83imkNrOpN8lkObHCkhXPfE2ljPyRSmGwAhQtpm2YN@zXsiuQb2iDyhXUtr@qbeZKteFqTdEgg9m3nW25Ktehuq6YBH/R5WUQu8rgFvBBLqhNRK2J2wDF654JVatt5coCRBoIxpyQE6dycFQoEY9v5uLxZLyM05or4C4YO7HgOPQK8bvajgyinlySt3Iy8PQJP7@WBD7xV9Ck2JWE41u2sSXFLqWry6vt6E7Jz9h4rIMELp67jHVSqxLL0JYgtRFjK2RS1CrNP@9WdjtPd8sCendPipVwX@9kzyU75XoalMxKZHfkbZ/t6gv@PcUdfhCrRLrFaqxOWwhMi7Qyf45H33ZYHLKlu/1aLrder@U2oUsHPhyA5nJaeTWVYTGVNnJCdXiXEi982taW2U5VM6eSLBMz4psbinmaGIUcvYtR82d7l8E0RwkvykjoJd7Ya/Xku8dW77K4rvDROHCfqysW4zvMc9d2mEPEwY7hz17m8lBPthM4wPjbB34PfWw@L0MCMi8H3pe54vqjwyP7gXtgBrOcGw25GmNZTcENuWXhmG/I5Rg7U@JaifbfDo63Xmy@KL549Ozo2dGBFDtdebviwGDu3ko2WyqWiqxcfmd/@jU2iK9vxKGaTiuxUWVDHCPRqlVF286xHSBvBqVwaLe1gpJ9W@XEWiWfQg683v/KDzZG20Ww50C0LkFp51O5alVbyyVjg/df/QGeI77c/3z3IYujXpe//9Mf5zb//k//Fe0ciV@VPZpJ3IwBJBq1wmbs8nJweXkFD/fLx@oxnqiNzSSY@Y4cLVbNCGdtU0vGPCUm5rc38zHvrfDKZfEQAvjuHXEHuZCHxhLbf2rlc9q9bawiLawiFv5tm95WTIoVH718yxhYjGqr07FyZMpkWOmdwrbfKdvsHU5uv1NW2MtKFdfQtEyGthjzidW1arWKaFi8msqsxVkuD361q3I9xWhiFsZ2L3Coezo1k31qg5PpreGfid5kX/M8sAY2c@2Vh0st2ybLVzUGA8RM5jT5/ld@M5cr/P2f/vrbxtvGF8C/t7a2Clou9jNI1ZKDrMEIj6aI8EgqGsKRIVtw97JqyFIML@RuMw4fjBNxZIiKHLgaLLRJ544ldB01oAR1EMsTBLaGx/HSJKDT2f1kWZJCKZYEcLdjpAkHW0N189DYpEvpDnpB38cqwO6kOxNU4NBH/VlGw@sN3QHJkgkKp9XT7C4EgRjuoMaVFTpGKHimopVZZu16UJ5krnyJpBXWNz0PVa4BT5fuQJCHQMV0@R0b6HgUFSEtG5i0iiCUTvJo1SDuOsTd4wEa5Jqg3HOANOOp44FsENClO3iujiR46NKZtQ0AZZaU7kABQB4SArFVZ9tsPckurVSqPNHRdoV7JVFBhx4cdJMwGGJr4enOIHAZ4Syuh2Xoom4yJmrYMKOOARKOg6/BVWBsgcHJhiIRnWW9NSrARToNEpQ1dvfuJFWVitVKMsoR4kcFdahXbqJQ61oEgCwYmH3UKslpZqdSWNl3pskOSjxFyQWqU8gwAWrjiUO0XkkS/N@aaJEiZ6qKPMqYAVFfvFUYUGQQGIud16GBKva03GaShYk3IO0GJYp09YSjzdPRRyqpzDJ4Eq@kn8UC1czAYk6iYyJBt7MnHRn0Y0NUmotqHDgzEGcY@R1fyKoO/SB0GAqyYvUIum25MLqglcNA609iXUtisHboQumg/ZC5DYZbFfNJ/FAohEbdMDrqWRHxrNAsOCmo8waOTYpZ6Ig77vAkdXmexNXQ8GQP7QudVKzxWGj/YyRFXG8dUj6pVbO57jiPh8VVSn6pgyibNDM7Kmkgym2xBNeEiJOWdoguSYEowTCm1LGMmz2zD0k6Nk2GqkG8UibTAXFk2CRdII8soKvugQUdhu1lxK2DmQvrzMqcoMJXxWmDiCvOnsZQgrFCxVxC4Qbp1etZZyYf6iamDg97LFdIgwiZhpKd/KBgSziFiweEs@Cd5lDw24TPJjcW05GwK4lx8vp3XVtJNLBG33IVVy7eLHiu25HypeetJAao3tgLNAPQUVWwqyHLhZbJjwPG8TxgeG5VEioMKnS8XsW59UECpK/gQCsaQWo1zwFC0STsY4BpGsFJW2zFkNs71AFQ24OWhcpzfLeER9ArqFYuYUDTEwzeZh@x9ZxESgZJKYPQoQA4sOor09jBD4JiPjy/BRWj8lkK4CvQOvst8IuhLilOfhg@oG40kyKpCXmzFYEOOx2Kq8J4swgs@YgFWwdXCwhZXwHPAqRwTkpWEnIK0KbkpMxRh@Fng3Nql4iXlNh1TGmGGERRAxYUFe7rHldUKvTeXFxcqKR8aehaqumhInAPb0zNDDoWiK1Oxjf7A3Gdk4W3@okbSycmhav/x7t1d0Z0pe3W3TH/SlIbD4O/HlqumYi3vTj2geeos7rTJ70WqHHCI7o5sEgdvpGgtWlPkFmunr4MyKyEZKYU41eIhDFEM0qP00YakKWbxlm6fdEqCw9@GTwgh8oyA0fUi@gGlr4XmKxBO4RwfNpaHdibvTPD6Tkoesh8MnYSNc9hADkOrMI@sEYQyDYv2K7r6uME@ScRGuk0MSbpho2hdycfMEJvwi65@jBrVBvXp4KPwuDQd4Ursi5qtZAulyPlWtvQf8T9R@A/4v6jSaRBtLVRnUte6HSF2UHiRjVVASSiGQcwV1zp3MSHMIOQzDSOAiHHU25X8DMqFDoob26DeqwEhAE0QboeE6hksnZatz3zYq2eynSApmUqCKhxQF2rU5letEIzln7vvDdwvCknG3U4Qecj0o1ORldQA6cVzGNYQUQYvLwsVPXT6at8Pob3@yLDgAHFLfBECWDXT1jJcqhklzyBcGrypIx5wmoiMXUSsoSXcAOpiBc9L9goonoEEbqHWYJkgg8LWo643EEwgecu3rAdwCp0WQNpC47X41CSM02Fs5QyVVIkVYoSJBOKHaXSymxWAn@oitqMVySbV6L@o8lf@eDkt6FdzE89ESzvF8pStKmYI9SNaormQqXKqpVIvUIKMmt6z3Shg9rnYqjolCGatUwwmuDxYBa4Tt9EpPKNJK8fOsgi23IpJIVxpQJZHFd4s@TtIihSXuBhME8EGweEIMJzBgI4snODmSLYKBpsVKlwxsFGC4JdRBI5okSOeBAOPVqQyLoIBoOkUGssVk8dlQWCQCUDPo33lqgYV2aefo7aj9krVO0Dg6cgzgnPISoQNISSNNKZUZ8bey2S6AjTmkGAhHgNQYvfJ1WSZhmepoS2kEfxogx4FLcJMuC8AgiMWHCZq29LhERGQ12Q6@UU9QPQduVUTZI13DhGf1n@k9OBY/DTrjtmpyG1acdseubvl@JYx5KNNNCIkKFlN5Ah44Bll7TZgFhy4bDEHOEZ3DPBXeSZZs9pZvo6bsPIuJEbypPBeIA0Vt4bOL7uOxsbJT4Isoi@nglwFrnRhY8BrI7twFAjqiDS4got7Tjq7TScjm15ZhrvROciuEk7Brjmdikq9wqj40mSmCTkw1JEzQkIRddGA2/BazQSntlrJ0uh9lW0qkiH8biE41kwRcIDHxJIjwYJp/nKNPzkzThRe6oIdmIZZ4mjgfCMQyS7DJiVAfI8@HZBVGGeMxkJklJDFI2bfoK023edvtMB8Q5VlmLoGfSHE9yYIH0woLSkmY5D1FJExyw1h4SR1pMi6GcfHJR9lkvoyTB8bhrBVGGkmTtbxliy7pzoGguj48GC@I4/PL3H0fQeL08vjapn08yH2hXu@WFRrycmGABwkoz1m5ORFhrCryVnKimhMwpQPMCtk9iibU4tTOkugO4KcLUN9JEObR5pLRIJ/3xR@S@vwCD4/m2rT8dLQY/HwG/6uJsuQTc3eMFSYgLAD5PIe65HF5L2g1vGBbB448oBygogrxLjslElFjTMAQyjPTlcRhGIb6B53Mp0je5pf1OFe85Jk3ueZme5xVX0oNEye/rYbCUEZDqCN8jxUxiZEb@6XcaR0RHTc/igLgGdVDKqURsLnQOVFpCMnj6P6FO/BsNBrJB6aOabUni4uPzQ/xprxim7Cp99BoE/Ho@R6n26KWEwHoy5KtEe6SQO@Cjvf3hN4tndmwsEykHsgkhPok0uY59PE2GWbtEjhLDqdJZJaVjQbTn9wfU6/LAiujmnULmRQJWglqfUnS@qcWtZjUeoIqBJvtpzO5K8iehuTXMRUuPIJixs78O6kGuYcfeDYSSiGLnL0hpz7Gs8Ad1o3s1e0Ks05jDUMCRxOt@icTXJF0kJh8CH8MUJpM/hiwg7pt/gBBXkDeeoxE04jHz6@iAitQgXkMYBS6QUg0stKBkRKCkwA/jlVRinsTBO41qcxlScYQuYjjICJBlTUYpawOpZVgU9s@0v4M7ohYNk@Cxj2/DYju7itMRl3IqXrDSLn8dLwJDjZry0nwCmHG/FSw/I4MVLx2Q4i5c@A8OkbcXfxktBs0AAF6xkuIfugoWj3YiX9hLJK8nHe0eCeNV4KaxTgNnhVioRKArMN0iNuGRmOyKbvmtCx0ZCZZohxXhpHCfRhEuafln45xcM8ItwwBPnLNcImKWYNtVpRHoMHg90G4Hi2TktuSR68/2jA9o9NLnBAfxTMJiLhiH0IIbH4tPMiCcMfWmFAr6QQOSbpfkpYtr0NR@3SI6IHSiUKnk6fio9leSBVoL8awBcT07fHiHCB/U1jYJX4O3SiYEXpfNacoLoKEW4xpqckyws1JfxJZnCup65GoXXfrSGaO56GgjvzA1AeC0R2ghPBxmOFtswsoEzmCYS8sU9gVY0DM2@8UaJ1DsTjLiCaJkLvMlZ5AwZQ7TxJ5dlJxIOkzbFgtCzlq3zVhb2C8SL0WvC6yKSKm98kIQIz4EWbhpnJpLtA2EkOM5u0tRXLOqGgrA8SuJc02wSAquohGSo@zz2cPC6j6pJPmz4GoQc4aRKAhFEQoaxcP7qfID87nD5PRCog0KYiWCeYD2/K70uXi/tZWdS3ptEe70C0TPNHiTnCkdhDJMih9FBRDJfRmvXRHzcwsGFfB5piH1G2g@KLRwT3FBus2MLjgulBPd82vEsB45nucUFdV0i6Z2rgdCiYkwCD894mNJJ1panlWd8XhWjD01k670PrmB3uoKjlYf4KAPuTJHzVo5HPXFta9K2SasvuiBL1UqMM3Ja/gyreeII7J6WYsNlWHA4ajx9cPT44deh093c3EyKPno8SR@2WpxUDftxjpl2Lof9wZxhSy6NWu1x8ZrueMb7p1dObfkaL@HMGoQBvM8nID/RxpOCl0X4@UzbhXAcNlKiAtfZpBnoU1wJRR0du2xLlKsPBWL6iTVdIAnEWyjvNI3WkjgnC9SBVwM2GtR9NRq4GanREL0YVk2wwp38WWwlM/RcusqX69y@kCQ6vM0eHLHnn@yesJNP9tnBs73P2NePnrHnu49P8LDzk2f3Hx7uMfjtPz7eZ5MZBXzwHhIcUEK5PjANs9/EK3@z2Q1GmPecwZjzncRekrsf6332iWOYuB617en9e11uUW3Tr/JQ@zAcHeMcpkWX3fQt3@e3@BmAjoSbFh1wwyMADGCbMKbt45i377SstgWwEo59B5bpBYewWM@CGgR@G5ytTHMhCe9Eoa1AdCMeXWaIt@EBPC7SABrdm9y@aHk8gNlSmSi48PngEjzZf/romO0@fsD2jh4/ODw5PHp8zA6OnoL1ydcPH38M5Xl4fPL08P4z9CLAR0cPDg8O93bJgScgqzI8zk7XGy5LgorgVCrGGS5x05XeoS066wxgIMGzC52O@nksPrSR@1h6z3pjtuJlCe9L4scLaU2AhbcVMvM1LmUGa760n0B@5tGNP6tZtk2xQWOpQnsri@YK3R5qXseFh/6Y4c1PZplOlCfIPLlRijbltCyTyXu45wTnvvnBc2rLAWqIaAVwI6pgA0qF0TUG8Xh6m1BWITaj56BmNh4b3xQoLBj0XrB1pCxRiYm9L4gUzwUc2jgfpJVDB6B7cMiJaH2XA7D10IEDsA3ugKLoIe4FYXkBMfSPhsieWYE7vOoPDmj9l22GDvd1GsUWRZp4vVGV6iy8SgWP4ffoIgo@y0M3TOmeYVkUxCN4vMih1wuueWyaQPLAE8WlXLhXDSBlYDZtXGoQ29jsITVs8AVqwH0/etv3WKKSVNkJbvYxbYvf8NHp6Tbf0jTZikO0x4qogqQiNnBb4dUZdNJi4BAB4nU20@kIwz0QUqF523AQ8v61GHWx55GuXwq2lN2UgPvXEvDzoAFEytRIx6Ceio57IhqnLUg54TlAkThv@y4KD@TcGhrmVIDgEs5X1ps3SVHI6alxUrDvkFIHVYT3lab5mmXbcaGNE1vt47kV5IJG1xn4Fq/DxHQOJleoATR2bBDby0p1Kja6NnUmRtuxI5E2gYoXxNoEorxNrETxfJE8ZF9BWw/vcKN9dJgcvYnXU0/WztK4iHRh4vQLCML8/knsbeg2YSF/ShPe8Y7uBC1Wqg/unyrvXqbx/gnOFvita8EmQn6HaB/jguZB63y0AdFFuUu0tOASE2/YxNBiT53gltjKA2QwDuxaMK671yiHfnz78HV3PJAy606Ob99WeCgFORPnyEOvm5hwtzSrBVGmKUydib0eEd4JiQVenwhc0oQz5Nf38OwJ1kIZSsRGPkK3/05fHiJYSJC75rANnEVcDyaqO8SfZFXaOhEIkvQkovWReZG4X0lVk5nJzhEWKc5EwKLTAWa8PWyy/4T6q2voHixHB/z79uiKS1PHu4cPwvZgKbYPSpuSWoyLd0sRXLdH@24JWt65/VxoIe/pxYh5J3kdW0jpIXGmV2Ph7tjlMb68VnfU9gAN9r04gxIijcQ2tGmJOtCVmuABklE0E4Ho@OTB/tOnTObjEwgLfA@HDC3BBhH3Cr9bhe@etWxidmooNIWD5VB4Clymtq4Fz7LGPLfwFrAKIYOkRXmEzGL6LlPieqJnIRGCdtMTQwxKbjp1lwEP8moC8RXeFArMKzYRw8IMSnOzGeOdj@VFN3WLcktz2Ti6J592TPO@G@8kc8dRRNHNP3oHT4rMr7/nXD4uBfFwAct8PaQMt0CSxot5VXYMEQ8AUFWna3BJtQRVipvmuYAdC8oOd3hlpyXsX5ygiJC4EM5l4QhbF8KxSBqXj1cDMYd2HmI3oOOWTuHJdyiDR8DiyWU7WqHJSaeXmO6CQMjE27LuRakCgtevyuEVu4lJP1kJBfJoW1ul1NSCVNZxdlbgLi8G@gj3Nhdm2cNsVMBtl0al/MNExXuJqZiCMp@bmcATMBfy@fWbcM/mIgiu/KK4eR8yyz/9/gDG9xOU3tij6X2g3MPH6cB/QgBLio5vlQ8azExAEHXm9ClTeafOKJo@SAufF4LEoOJho4t3g03HmmSjmbTNx857pCh2ArmWh0gTDjPKW8210r9aHh0y5BvjW/nw@HhjQyDcI3j1s/BwXUTvSsQJz5VOu5muaxMYP5bUd/D4GJ1GWnpmjg7N8Q2tPDPoScts0Qy0xSEjvq02HUwxUCQ0q6jiXYI4qVeendVTtHI0hweHD/fZGumra09NQcqunIywnBXLXpYAYr00HYG9Bh3F@8grwQ/SkA5QQjHRobwElU3yxrRRiYCwXKOrHsS2T8FStdlKb3uGbqMSkLRMF3HfhYA0@bp/dJCcN6GeLU@Fh8R5AzsBodKyosoUFNxwHhcxTaPgtYnukX5KwrsOxAbJJTcP6xmtmC1sSZQ7O@2n@7WtenrNqMgM@lzd7ntD96J11nG6523WY4NXzZExfvOasfwGW0eFk3e5vkytUMGjqwmGGkaKbCtLBCsSuEMaSU9lxlTStYjryWwy/C6vsCQZaKxcwhMQM1TK1voBFeJJOb/SrxXqFbuSLfdrdr2MZ/X8VMVPaakEOtyFzhNYC1@Qr/l17Ep/Fp1tNe1z5g6bYxglhWc/GJ39wP4dZ7jEnm2aL6dtxtId3KyGZ0hU27xIhPeqI2VKKP9Id@gQj4ZHw2m6GGdbWhakAEo/DcKqN6L3OCndyarDge@Qj4hIQRJib6230p3g1FGWJgwApGbVg@RsE54JTALXfbjrmO@GVjQujWl41DEZQVHDkMTt5FNZxiOAmFBx9KpWlzzV1I0uJgLvz3xLwdj2Nt2mCSTlqTRJhzs1dJcOPmTraMT1DfgMaDEBoyDB3KPjGxJkH@0aGrgLTUH5dN6FNrpLJAiiD27jZpd0HInCb0MB8IK/w0UqVcxgCsEK5ER@1I/mDlD13PS4HlcR8BQkr5Q7mFnEzeOrTJDTjm8qI4xWFBO437nA4uRlBY/IgaKR7Vo2QvgkB6cioWVoYfOwLKlKyauKn94kWCISTAmCBcCRorhzY2ngRBaMfh6Z0HzGbM/s9SDRvCzuTIoDjXQcV8SfCuP3ahhnPUw891eu@StT/ir354maQKnQf0@ASlEgOXY5gbti8gQsfS2uCiPZRIWaNlSQOCaw5WWwnuo7DWsCXA2rklNl6LE95aFEfF7MqX3uszIVJiTw0L/G/QV950TNh6mcgr03HT9@JVFBJu2NFVtJZqhUta3eDu@cQh8kMxlKkzEeHOubyI43SnFkUrATENBwGp@abbUywZLSAo5DbUaubt@TVSFM7CRmk8EPHV5rWHPaSKSUKM4UFdyIzhdCPOS9EkFBOJHQWNByq0HgsQg8jqBFqJUgWn5o8VoDh6zNNvEKHmN8i6@gsU8nLoCLzfe8w1M@4pnnh5GnC4iY7oo8v5imuQke@@COIlNLepFJ3ONZjPOZxOPIJG8Yp8mPTLdxlnsl5BNRRhFwimvlHvqIkp4AaAH5LqpC9LySfpZZkz7WQYQe9MwR28VRhE6nqaSp8@iojdVDRUmks8UbDgY9XFQkwe6CTjwL3R25PK6mTDBGltFU6RA37nD4NJrE@XEIpLIjxHyB@z8mHt6wg7d647oN6kcC1ooTKpavSrv2mM9XQJtZz/FT4SYbenxRFAbznWgieM3x1oMl7Q10w1QlkMU8kHIkntU2b99iuhyPhaCqLujSSpL0taFlnO19jMu1m1p2XYsU2blY7c2q6xuTg1JQSIFHLgvial7bkKTI0q/Bl34VRJhmD7Gj/xxo0zzHu6OlXegxCNAD4dT7f9t7tu00kiSfzVekC1tUSdx1N0LdSEJtemXLI5AvK2lQAQWiG1EMVUhgt/ac3Yf9gf2A/ZR92E/ZD9mNS2ZWFkKW@rLTPXOmz2mrqMpLZGRkZERkRKQ3vvE62UTixNNnvNgukjIePGLYtD8Zt9l2A7IV3jmN0b5Bmk@7gMLwL@7PfBrcpqOwdALPpKLDZJjqm34HEagCSro@Hv7SeQRG9TM@sNK1FwJSlh0RB4mOliUsJLtco50JsIFpSYyjB42GoR/22zAzZKhKDKApPuWIOht25iCB/toDF4N8s4sAwOiXCAMKAHVS9DUYEvJM/GfBIOTA1BG6q2YmB9zPp7UCy90b94H7RgimWaFqBuwwwY3XtbqoHx82PlROqgKe350cv68dVA/E3ic6wsZzcEoPK14fHwF30YflfCh@DC@sSh1qWvQhUXn7SVQ/vjup1uvi@ETU3rw7qkFr0PxJ5W2jVq2nRe3t/tHpAR2uQwvi7XFDHNXe1BpQrHGcpl5VtURUTxwfijfVk/3X8LOyVzuqNT5Rj4e1xlvsDA/tK@Jd5aRR2z89qpyId6cn747rVYEDSxzU6vtHldqb6kEW@oc@RfV99W1D1F9Xjo7mBnr84W31RJAPgDHKvSpAWdkDVRV7onEe1E6q@w0cUPS0D8gDAI/Sov6uul/Dh@rHKgyncvIpLRutV/90CoXgoziovKl8B4NL2I9gBeZl//Sk@gaBBkzUT/fqjVrjtFEV3x0fHxCu69WT97X9ar0kEkfHdULYab2aFnh3FXUNbQC24Ds8753Wa4S32tsG7Bmn79CdwYFJ/gCIASgrUPWAEIxeDjhaQNLxySdsFfFAE5AWH15X4f0J4pSwVUEsoMPEfsMsBh0CEhvmMMXb6ndHte@qb/er@PkYm/lQq1cdmLBaHQvU0N/iE5AOdHpKo8Z5Arj4EYg1oSg3TdMpaoeicvC@hpDL0kAB9ZqkFkLb/muJc1jLuYRhLOn7aBtwr00DSvf@qxsPEzvet7wstsXoBEf7xwdV2JFlBikr@nAKu87WXOYj8xvsNPoj/IxlmOl4rUmv2R92fYwV1dXYwHEd9NJ4NYcD6rk4T3zldhZpR6EKyWSz@b7SBEW33mw66afUjIHxWA1p5f5aKUeOEbPEo@aNBp5XrxjvOzFE7S7Jc0zyw8PzBSzJ2F9izzb32nNELtfxZDUMwseGlYko4FORKzwpAdZIsYx4KUXUJVkg6HdfkgNVtFXz2XYTzaDo@EiF/AD@Gf4U/eDNwXgB3JnNWrkcKrEERv@zp7rhTii1Af0jMwv0u9RlNvC8H3t23uwOdf5sz/c7tuOoOlQ2BD2wZzuPVG95vbnqmfn6BCydKsvk8oHSu0mE0cfLEmVCzkt2TCOz8Z9mSH8cBQ3nbkCjKHVFtmhpnLSXuDo6HKWFTFGB0RM0ySjzval8rH1AbS5fXCvNvX@t3/PaQndATE0LG94Z1bugP68vuAAsMMqpASjpy0wXuZxRR7mT6MK3UPAKC1H2fdqrrzza1wElIMhO3IHZJ@7G4/7UhB748HcnlTd7p4eHwDoR2rWt9c2NUkJnyfqY5r@fsB9KmEpJwkawj4OcRp@MVbIPgg@tFCPLdkT@RMC5HBbEPOZq0ugl5mvQbhlxRyVkZDjcAG9oGaIHnuUhHixBiTSeJxS9LlyZkgDs2FAdHM21OyUR3wVZiWhA@qoMZjRrU/wH29bLXy1xPSBJQJLEKE0tUC5oF8T3rEPlCUrKDeXZwSJZS9ExZ13TOCBTF7nHYvAs/ZK0bcxiwJ6KuF5p2qkmAPF8Hgqh3CaGvLLfUb4QaeilZF/w5qOkN3j8JPPRUXY6NwgrYR3QeKhroj06MjrLQZ/Jli92yzBFS0u6px2B1nxHAkVrT5qNdYIPYzUQKBfoM1gWcw2XdD6Q@S7JwfXblCO@MKViEg5spyQpVv4Gyl00HNlKSeUBkb9VdgnBbelkJYy1W91HQhX5pPNRKHTG0PSr8EHt/444WdD@Dmic0HqELSNn35MwSa0yrkB9JaT0b9WBgnGKEWHTfPUpaubOnJgrPTB5SjPl8BlAgZydmXrxibIUdu0FCEAiR8OGuX61x9mVC6rTt5Yjq@N5yLB9PbKF3CvUVnGv3czGRZrErrQ6Q8EfjnDY1mR0eARVxbesuLVo1YPKNKfKi5eBxc05Ko9HbpkMIHrBE5VesVPqPGXl5SpTfECmTDI2nI7OfARi6d2Dp3PLwshoGeP98oRLIQqa3kV47o@T0pr7gr1v4wkSOY16g5LWYWZtVJNx85EZ5lrkZznwsJ2XHTKG4M2z4S1uEANunTLrRa0J@yX5gWAnkVNhlBYQ2a2TBdTStnqroSfLJFKohv50yPnpPbZqqRJZzt8hITSj4bPijTsDkAdPGzaTWG657qfRNRE7Y7OErI@37LZ9fwyio4vjBhjT/ZmTFR@k0cEbBpOxTDcI@1l/LC0SSuiHblBsYu2dthlOhU6gBf0QgxE6WaIPGtK1hw6gnH1kmtkQNhCvotFdZXTsT1cKwt6JvuwATiiLKCFxR2yIn37iUoxQmeHTIwz2A61ckEsm9YPnDnr53frjH3HvRxFo2PE6OpGo0STZAnmSakNKydgOeegjPyCLBkwFWkA0JgpsSNN@qLBHb0pykm5LVpTMElON0kh@fj@aSJUzFHQUEa7sHYhvIwOTiVgqykyeOrdnobhOoCxSuO4eVMYouWf8eFpY50PNUl6xEFF@qURHfGK@qZ8@4ZM08pdfBrh64A2eZUsRFAFGmRXPT@/zOYIPE/N96HvjjmkTBUmm447Q/Eaqjz8kWlSmQ5m@r@2GgTcDDaCd609z1EbT/t6/Gjb3/YHb6/t9F/Q0zIk@ZY6HjzN6xAnrjf3bgK7SoQ8do1BnFj1z@hhOp4a/9blkyUixFYTeyDbdEcLxrHLFWSDIco4@fkLvV0Tfo/lcZ7rO2npUKREPLyV3u4JTerDuamFRZT65xwYkg9ud85TgENGQ4o6M2NLSvQKtrxUwYGyJjHCdBxzyYhBvA4roGCYGsQLmnvuBOQjUzB6E@KwzTXcol@AY8yh5Bx5eRhPY9Drt4i2swEW@QY@AV6KwlTeq8inKFPMJ4sPsYXQXN39n6AGAXwF@YXURtSwiBGJxXZVMKWB9RSYFBVjI@69PPJo4MXCxfg92oUGs0eZ0vtX459lD2CAPHxCKZLq8e1SJK9IGxQcvYLObwHKaMwc3lZRIOZSWA0WQSmjnHyZY7zH3WFr8eIjLljNkTPuyZdsA@iFUtQFLeK3mnPesCTKnQH58xRSLT521OQSWF3mUGVc@2JaSXCjApM/7Kx5r@WNgxtYc9qSrRyoI/VHqidh7kHcszLC2CNdtx3nUz5eJrQyb5XKHUFue4eOslJiHZ45o4hgjjzKgIVRf6VmT@TwSp@Umrrdyc/YIHh7CWeQfpTcVPd8dXvu4Kd6gw67aaPSSItgx2WhJvz9rwsCbD3MQ2SarV03iGE1kGc0ZPxpNzaFJY@npGCLqk7DP4aMDmMN@O4A7c34eROq8M5xKXao@xZJVIj4xzzrGZAJfGnXR@QKzwLGEq5mUFjin6Rkd5RUyLUwWjB@4QZSKvUxkh2ILbjRZc3REyfy7dhO9hQrIieBp1/Rw0Dn6NcIoib407kiPh@YsU7gocUtT3RJoFVTqay2pcHL4edacUiv3UAFLfAEq9Iju8aarp4/q144FykELXJs@S0fefBoH44gVgAb@MT81pygDR13JmrEVFV8ITWINsBZAS@kNPFZXUfrrj5ni0btBLiNQIPi1jX9WZA3Mvr2R19jGKtPODIs4Et282hyR2eUqEUHxb0S/XIos6pLiCg14DDHULxegBUxPStDjoQBl1jEpLwaonCOoWC7gsoSXlN008udc8B2RKgusrRsl8otKbJttZBY2AoLF4jIRICCzLC4StQIb3UJYjBKbi8cTlQCBWNE@YxymQs5KHId65hiB8EjQao5yVhDpvKRg@ri27sQ@avqmr9t542t@/ivgR0N4linMf93Kx77Gui0W41VjNQEfjtlr7COgwjEB1lzh1/1HkSdm6nLtE2ooGTEpQ/phD1GVukW9LftDIHYo5lrJGKo9M/BbqV9NvhElllz964nUhUzTX/r1g1WOqQoQmdmfss6pUBab9UESWC3c6XFUqOiqPHo6/YBSaf2ueN84PIwldW3NlJ/RtTdez@fzSMMtM4e9cqFGS1Lfz8VL57qTwSA3uv1@/L6VI9aPt9gPAv@VUqA9mBFYE0HWH/f4HgeEAYpi6YwMU0VVf9Ltmhcm4AElzh3MGpeUuQ4E7T997fPyvkH2H2pS7q@XOEAc36XQi@/WZTlTtqJOoaA2egTfWOrwDNCDL7rohq0Pqqgx5MvKmQm2Lae8@wU3ELyHhCaLshA7XyLvZOu1Nxj4afHBHw86mAfg2d18hcNDs0Kei@ABI8XuTgLKNpsW3k1/YEQNYxGT1LE5tS@pWyFUendMcX/i9arTkW2d/dmCXQWGvILDXME002lh9SxH5nx/QrNMhwD2k0pfuyO7TXiaLww7vVzA0RNAtFpIL1R9YkUcMolJnD1eGpG6GNwspWKAoTskCqiU9DS9NJIHimvkWufTQhdxmOc2JEyYUeVpNTCQ7Pfjijdht/s0pkjZ/Hli/@oMkY4AaAXK5Qf4xGTY/5SBZX04ly6E5Ru8c@M@38EKTayQSLxsl/9ya1cqFfFitLIiKpU9eMhkRGWvIg7wxd6eOIDfe/h7qVxcXy8xzz1wvsDLPfXyTuxBG2TgXGlfjQ/gJ3wrY1QYOmvjFL/IlV@kSy@a5Z3dUpA7q@xh0D48/c@//vv//Nt/5Cryx3/ijz36cfZnXSibzeZetL@8WLor4e@zg4vUi9bZi9FFqldCKkN2fzoO3IFreI9m24lHIqQ6g37roagp7T3TD8hVE90lbfinXAYN7Kef@Ok8jB7H0SPmRI2qu4PRlUvVBbWwW05VUktL8LRTTv1zimwn8r2r33@G98JBXk5JEwi1eO@PqNT3azUz7ThyfZLeux7myMHLLmW@HHlwdZlUNwNmzkQ2Ky4y4lKDh24eTS4YB5HVTAbmXySQanTkk0Nn11JtwENpMn2zOZ4Ppq6DHsl3ynTOl5@5UlN52XnFZ2jUxgowPCxfYl91GfeKwwdw8dirnDkrbKxfZJLJZEJfiNZsE5uj3kbUl74gSx2hU34GDsMawZKBsdMFdWXEBTSIyEgm6bqspTZf62YPUbUmjYkV7mTKkOfR3kQDSWg2xxZuTqaAMhYqfHQFmQgmFIWBssHsqWd4AACF1@0Q4xJ8W3Iw8tr97ky7POCNFFHvsFdiyNyy6N6LmBPWuGXJcT3vRg0CQlAKoFw92Oh8g4w8H8r2idvxGNVvEDfuE9WlTP4t1miCtUPQyB/MegPozCZXquAWuBNg3pGTNRiqUDrsgWu2PJB6PLmiecIiX16Eu@WhKWLYxhMyvB9qgDm5WODj41/KRgnrASUceT9cF0NB7MGQHYj8LjzCho9RdHyERWS4gluqJChUalE5VvfLST6wPHIcMeKSiFX4HR2@E3mQCZL0YXnRnUwTwqcxI0fWxLc7ktJGeLUfKtIyN6gjV5JFa0WfvoFUeY1nlXhOCUjBklm6SwxYw0xcDoaXevx8uhngdYRZS3XJ3RTZPwE4lu5GhctTdxwLYLFxlW4ewxNOeWG2HwT9FiALhiiniVIgcvDAGFo9TyW4M0kteByICMZXyyO9oszxKVLypiOKz2d4n6Fpd6ioIFYQD0jxTMzDszvMceBLlge/hv4wQyy35YX9NjtQcu/PFS8e4bk4HVMSYA93BMqDi@PUE0w9nKvsQvK4mKY6aofwhMEKuP6vtOjtEs6kmVeyaBk4AgBp4tCzcx4hKWpRUwI1EEeKhJH8vyUGn8UIc@D1@mGsTlpmYGC3cx7FnUI9LvJLBNjE7hxmMVBCnTRrlnAp8a1cM5Dxqm/AaLccGfy8iPbUYHBX44sndU0eEsXTbd2nD82PFDgm1LCCAX24fNPxGaLNFfc6SiKHqTw7cVIV0Sx8tQdqXILI/GKZAnyoAckt5nGSOQNsFOewAex0bhlEXDgfa94gYCRucycnHjWHXp4uFgnuMW9FLwpSJIK7hA7p@fL/3W9sKltjjE@GxQelkA5gj44cTnQejfkmF67AW08J6jI5HrDG8QQz0rEji9xRMIVNnxep0amGY64rNXQ5wxmSlEaUHwV@nqXMuZyrqsYb1b6I186kOKTriwrssg1JZ@TIeC/59Rlv5rCbqnY5YouO3ujXnQotk5FZ2mFCzY5EOW2vbhfRgw4xdMeSnpy7RaShdHjF5dWYpWQBwmWscWqLjmhkOdMnaAGS2FehMgn9Wvjby/SUW1qe9emXdN0qyAUuiMFSRHCdnHyCR/Q@dn4rtQD5QB8YAfuvuYEHz4kESx5Sw7TeBL09f2rn0@fWuZUubGw7FunJWg5LtgPQjJJtj7Ol4ZWNUvekrIxk177xmIWPW/1OxxuqXKxQVfamPzVls2dozv@i2V3AN9xaxMQ9y@DlQQYmkV5IXNPzaOz2rl16fOs3xu6sBpsQ/Twe8nzWsb0T2IzwTib6csJrtNIBUcO6Qz05ooknDZG8olyQfNohiQacic8QFxYgwLuHAO5Tjz@ID9ZAgzl@tl1o6Zn2TZjUS5ZQAnaivuSDk8sEX/h7jTfSNvkd0KZt3AgsH@nT3DXVUkbAD8pB2HjLNVjUH@BJjzeMnUOo1MGS8PjaaK6VFgMg0LxSub4@FJ/9oS819MGlVGzC9lXzejII@3Jk94alxoWV5u8@JnVSXVf9wP3HZDKcx50xDmz3rA@rNNJliFFFWJBKmGrF0B8Vumn8ZHaMhAapqnDaj@Ia0Uf@rvSVuWHpflepGpiVwziwUcopjjNhqBtQu5SI9lmhR/08pnwgHIAUBGN5RBdPE2u@M@cYZxjzhhAz0ZP719DZ/5aVXH5Dpw0RlpReKt0zmYdFuj5FFaRFXh5iG1otUArfPO5fe1KzleqEobwat8ZxMs3fXWF9RHOLSX8GqpTXtim7PI8ttJhwqPw1DXRqIYZ2ZnMWaKymMGJKEsRyRjIxAuNZtnTHUekL2QYrJVCSYZ4XspXEpEe6gL1BE/c2z7QWI@59cpT0piUgKgo01VFMVe5u0cYm/X3RqhftYArWuExpiuwi2kAjmXWBEq7J4FFEefcRVfhliGK4FuGJv/xmaIojII6lu0RiEflq1iFds8y1riOI7vElQtxzLQjPtbFA0G0NMGlgBNh8czCBSrLfVsLwsqj0gC3GZWF2DHejd6z1sAIZzIWMa0MchyFMxphUNwnSVQL@xwTHwKWu0aATs4CAyJpL6EIUH4bYIHxra4RMWSBySSchfYZySb4mqLBZcKiTJ/SEEbi/QrxnNohHMd17wW@4oZDIsSyaMoDw8d2P9roHzNKx8S00SQNHjozSzJ6XRyMMKnjMSp1LylQWtoDmhSN@oYGabCVF3oPQzpNLJp4BCCxpYE496Ixqr0gDb@DBMHRGTjbnRm5YrB8qQ/cfyf6tcKx8FSQFaAEhr6QDlM/oCmieYCkhUCArLdDUyyAFqNaxMwt7iUQ1EhcJtTFKVjt4QW7VCw1CelZolw5EdIPqODSsigutpspCJJILqwkbU4yiNYOOjrw2GsK1lSpwDHuwNDvkoG15IzeAxYGSuskYuzKHs7QkJGxksp6TMRYq@jFEMRwxZJwPZbzFHOkCE8KXhHi5pcAy0VLfaKH9gQvIEtHqXFosiCB7jeSQyEKTi/A@GWrML8YOVf0afigYwp@LNyKcEEfVuV8iaBI/F6Hz@HyESMmg97dDpT9rJp5KqvLe7odokffizQLvxebeMwtyaG3A3Qf/9tsc50uBpdH@I5bN4OtnvP@SmQL@YQKleIVQJxEAbh@Ejrxr/Fmk12WDsMnXpmv2i3qcdLnrdGA7BmZLAU1p0BND8kESBp6Vgy0lGPhZG6ZS0rl7yQpBxURQ5jUzWTvSywQpZob6q7ISEKa6Moz7GTRH7kUUyYlHV36b8wLABoXfu5QVgPTaAqtFqBBxxTP8KWMqn3U5TWFXrmQegVhuym7lGCQ8NAiWsfbGbvgkESs6kmOHfTHEJFEgZc3TYZBNiNrPF8meIpctP1kuSy6TTXs5Es@WkyOQLVZ/YRt/XTktMtBCO5aG3MKFSgZ8UjkAxTBBA/Qwjoz5kmuZR26/XOz7h/jyR90Ylv/w4suyRn87LsQsR0JMe6EQExWQtdpoeKN6ujyxB1i2Q9KQl6XYw/358f5g3aj@/IX98U3sIionK/vULb5e0G1468samlBlh2R/XNgR8lpe05eWXNuXwr6/oHm@o2149R/b8N/3NpzTuMBso4/sNMbU/2Pu/x7mHvNXDrbyW/nmb3buq99ZJmFZc@etQljPRWH3m83z6UH@fLq9dvyXZJjcLeY@jOFvmPxLcmMryY/wAL9W1a@b5G5yB4tt3CVnuXK5DI@ylcohtLL7vW4TS8124J/dddXuxiy5mylT9Z@SuxvwUCgWAZLzaXX7fLqVx/@t0h9J/DBPV7Tw8VCrI8ppIzcEPguULvKklvtB1OS@sTvUkASUOh43kOLOD41mCGB0npkWt/JSVgEC4uQPN568f0ulzZDyI@WPCSmjCUdcqLQP0lePK8EK0F048Ie6oN1eil5RwgmVawKlhAhocfkyu4FH15cyB4UGQOebIDGTXblBvbCpY0xvhn93899YOh/FKyuWBCN@til3xS25K/5vUoxm4ZU/LC7Iap8U@zBdoSd@CBiWYNgfjbyQJf6eN/TGlMoEhoOCDl6z18ZLCQf9H9n975VqXLSpoeYPQZNjc7ih7GgmrBffwsrqX5NW9BlWpXrG87GNNfULGDde2IZxMiq6ptcPryYtupCgMZ7VwmPKRJHDpOYhZ6XIgSzXyl276DhAafwDIDEoAexgPBnm6GI3ENgwVgZz71@7PwJoeJksDK3ThGJo7P/RpptbA29EIS7Tbteia5K8Qafujdyxyxnr0Gt@4va8GmbigckIrixUnpLiLQXXhGZqYq0sEcZBDpf3YWU4exjx/iClwj8JtUJguDFd12NhnLpkQsS7rSxFTUAti0ML6Irwru@HUXmOGtcV6Ge8BuVjg0ni0BA8HIxGBNwcx7@igFgRQr4gOKKfstPoBXVE0IxFH6/RwFF5w8k10Y6@1vas8OpC5qwrF4zrxcnjdeuVvFLeshChOE3S2FzYwi8T9r2kc8mETB2gxwGCNUMCBXlCJnRaeA2aQhD4rR8o0RJyJViQSH9Z9U0ue3Kjh0c0dg@9nku84raFyXjgbacfUAGsmet9BtmdUZSOkWpr0guyvBYosKIfBBNvfXNrjQCiHV8V7fjtWNFiDloeu@NZjoC7Cq8HehTb4ZUYeDfeQHqvENiUzpcXJdEZ3mjmTgbk1rLhEOkAKmMjBSzY22l@d1A9PKo0qgdpEFPWsXhAYUm6rG0glz@v0PfuADM1MBlhFV6@2dbGGhO5HaRT36JFjkH/1kT7igmwaiAIsrgH9Ed2qkzVpJ8FNyxGqLYPe2l9HE6phlTWaFxuCMqErpqwFHLVyk8mMaQrwL6SSIKxxAZQBwemIrfHA2A89wo9yCsAA5K7NUOgyAHyT6Rca@d5JqPX1Ct6ygBjzWR22chi7Q/6oHimTibDGLdN0dpxRQqYHB7/M2t7niK@kLVK4qqMenypXc6XdNzejT1xvugrqbsIhc2Ia/h7MzV/9kRGplmAEIe8nFXI5H//V8op3UVJdAZ26ODVC@JzWWWOzjJTr/JdtXYqaMNkhVDtczb0puE@Z/oshyVdoeV3ZllKrtXZB626Y382@xjZzhfYq1dW2uXyqvMFuhyPMAPoCJih14AWnRK@68be6RCx3Pn5EC@gXsbQvY9vjl7DlKOfmBeEZ3@@WH6RS6dSjlPCIbhliu87OH7zDq38YydL1v7DsX8t8TJ2dSdZmO3r4Cx/QdCnLRxaDlchcM6eF8rRB3uzhtt7C9KSnXIBBeiWRIFxMCn9HVfGl5XQNwllLrycxcRR2YpPruV86ZWp1NXY65bYVnEXlG/snlMK4c@V2cU6dFEuFqn1ECqV0atpDuv9IezWrxtvjsqpHVdgq@UFqyK10tLEAYRCBGPjqwpeRxUjHeAqRFUhR@sRwcB/KylrNz6WnZy7myrd3T0IzxHn0wXhJxURcMeepCXFjcv3p7Q0jqhgNvLK@IK3tu@qDSsNdTEFC74c4vY2I6bFQaxl1QeTG3IK2gJndSxTLq8tLdE7rDIJyuViPu9gRpQ7aC3A@@OhWV5Y49Ld2C13bI1Id9RfcFtSMVvMcSBLkCtsFPPrm9/4Y9giyngh/VIALKSMWstNP5wtgWzoldXNS0sgJ8NuWn6@trx13N/708ft@saB3W59X7DS1g8Bue2PRyYAY/c2y2IR8NixzLVLQGDkYtvNjdwf/dxaJ98GybOw2fE2172t/OpWe91b3W5tb2@3u2tbrc72pru53m7lMNk7Vcle94cgJVlM/tht92ndPiSYbRXz291uobCx2Vnf7m4X86ura62t9U5@ba27VXBXVzc6xa3WduvrUlsETwIYrOK7uHfMc@CXDwt3iXu8XdZ2/g8)

Before executing any code Refunge processes labels `(..)` and string literals `{..}`. This is done regardless of the position of double quotes.
First `(` on line 1 starts a label which ends at the next `)`. When execution reaches the place of `)` the program is still in string mode because second `"` is part of label name.
All we have to do is to leave string mode and send the IP down: `"v`.

Main code is on line 3:

```
@.7.8.2
```

Moved `xy` around `v` to fix AlphaBeta and Beatnik.

Answer (score 2):

## 289. Befunge-98 ([efunge](https://github.com/VorpalBlade/efunge)), 13510 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                 @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      # ????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 (   *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa











































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu91&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在5"" 16 ""6int 21*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]putsR 8ogrFloat 
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
.exit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";   print(85) #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQdBgACbzSbv5dzuZg/Jvn1nQDS6ABSAugSq0KgCCTTJjplZe6yR5LU8O6sYjXZ1R7PWWrI2YuUNrzXySrsR0tcNxX7SD2g9HA6FQ/MPxueczCoUQABkj6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4YbvfnP4/gw547vUmn53jMM12PtYbWhTlU2aMJe2hYbk7PSBKG2h12Rn3T9tyiFGEaY65nDD3WM@zOyOiYLAKuOpva21bPM4dJ5poma5g95xL8M4zZ5iU7tJtWCyAxzzk3beutOQS/LGOPzd51/9pjTaffN@yWywZDy/bIN8fYcwMs7VHznBkN1xsaTc9ybPDKM/bC7hn9RstgFHwwNHmkTQagmucUZ9anwNhTZ@iakILTNF3XQcctcDSGlvNk99knc@G1NPvEAKQGPXM8l7ymsZeWOWzNx9DZ56cHB/OuGfaZ4tjs4DZKWpbtjjzn0JuHn2O7HdM2mK5uqfq8Zx6I6Zm9QrqQnvECvwNrCKVpiFIrTkvGHvUb5hCIL4rw0vK6KkQ4dTjBmWP3JswcAzDAsQ3BTI9ZWFosl05jSPg/MZuO3ZqCBycT4ABcsz/wJkxhtiN4ALycIXMHRtNUWmbP6lue2WI9C7Bz2gIbl0GBs3NzcukMoeAVzoqEiDswm1bbwigiB66EzPbYbIw6zBl5gxGg57KW5RqNHgRrTFjLbBujnpdkDfAD4pH7Zde0BUqW3cF8vJy6IAQbqgDHfl0D2li9HgN0zhEdTNpl2@hxie4YtGESlmYLQe1PyQWQjJ7r53424ZlkMN7zodMZGn1g1JZJNPj88Dlzm84QbPDDsLwWrALTNDy2vc2i@88eR1klIKM6bEgBScvsijEW8T3ZhdEbmS7rGxNI2/agcjGHys@PIUFwFl2LFlk0k2F6mmWzLAuVrcD0XJpBldgCA9RaPaPBL8/0AstqwPe5aBLTaQ@NjtUzOZSO02sjoE3kWD3HdHins9Ek921SGpssU2D5TbaZY5vw3mJbOiSCELNM28rBLw8/gLAFGGjwy2R5SgFbIDtBFtgeaxt9qzfh0AcDBN9kOY1tAkRAUwPIeqGAsWefMCyvC0TtGhcATulZ5ygqzEBaYEml4JPa2EiRuEK5yJNzu2avhykCkYA8uQLbhBTzkOEspAo01Au6n/FOl7JOOG2m4Qf4bUJuC0DaNFApjWTahB/YQQTpIGt0ECw6yApdA3cdzBmECuHy4JeHcsoHZNVbRFeQrBBXQ0KiMNEw/xCNQbFlsgwKLgtFm8GizWUY4AkIbOYZyJOCxgpZVthkhQLbSjMguwbIYLlrIMc0QEJDYFCcGpSnBohowCgaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFMtDz@IB4UugZJapCmrm9N2Qpw03OQyVyG@E3PQ9Fvgh8QSwdcdeAUHbDVC@CPcQtAuAKy46ZPCKM36BpICygBZGJgMyBIDnAi2BAezPpmhrMThW6YntWUbiSoUbz1C0sbX3Jg7QdJwgyGjScw35R7YoH0i4MwmhVUI9fsAReB/GgaYEaWhZqOUsOHY3kqylhookznAhtRqvozybgkHhpDbEFBVrXM4ZBhWGho3SQJEnfUcM03I2xnp3i1QTKZIFTbhtULEKBqY3jUBsA36kJ6k1m020OnT3Wrj4Ki5ziDJSIXxNIlAvrUuTSnqE@lljEY9ECWg7sJhBgZPUDm0iBdgFSFcKocIYiE8ZpdCwBSUiBTraHZJNqLrEPsDEjfWRSLTK88yCCUR6EmIcMGDghUF@PYo16vCE2d2WSZSqplXqTQhTcbs80F4uA3JNAWChANA9pxakgRiwDSA12lJurUL1nX6c9mjYuXwyDrXQvFf@/SmEDptUGymGOjD9oGwybdhka7DxzDSxBLwuWNziFrOXbUC6BcDqFphUwHOQGQPaKJZ/VN0MUciIIlniWkUbgRZo0JsDJRK6uSKsYxmSOUKs0TijtkQw68skCj1ho1kWqYtmUTB0Fj4FJLVQG4XOFU0QBVbmgaLR4MNQvEKKQbQUtnAtGFGtAkQKidmLYLmo6rMgtVQmD4jtMGHqPmGdQMiDpNp0l5x5wHTmO1qUpEaeSb/nmPWaw5GDBwB90E0DpIF6B9db602Fvw7HVd1muOhsMJGw@gAKw@hPKaTrsNTPvWHHQBBOu3WHPShFppeFLLIeHTHMzlNrCtmxDGNiHHe8@/wTomEBoa4jYgSUw@xX0wIOyJCobNG2nbACIh9s3BhCgCYIIYbcdR0b3lmC6xBygxQWXHxFyzQ5UBalZ7Kn76qHQAX4IiYAO3gqwRFQrhY4LSwsxgUqLcPzFtqCxN4EOo5lByqIbusjao/KE2GnU6o9k0B57gDIcEmGWH9JijA9RjyFURwFS3K60/BBVsBgMJgko@04Qab@Oc5Crq96ReGShdRb8CmnPbDDRXxmVJb3IreQhxMZe6/BrDzGDwWl6Cw4AqASp1JBZGHgoPlIdWs4vSz0P5QgoG1K/h6Hb2wS2c/LDPlHaQNmKjgaCR1FTghHgsh6HAr3cbkDroIazKjAMGnXG4A7Th9hdAdgIke62wq5oyVBCDdwHtO7azACoQM4CLQWZ9qCyIGU9QYBi9gBmpurgzZYQietrlxaYLWs3BwBlCzeDyZoJCjBdZiLsc3j2JBa1DHLrLs40pNBJRbOI9j3e1Bj3o/lAVw5oKqqQBQgLkF1f8Qdw5PMUQwlTrCZbA75KEPWcmaD1t20Rt1BhOOBDIHjTIkNCEWcMhSMALbBZ4q@M3HyrxKbQCRquFQhXJQfV@PnEVOXpv1LDG872LJjqqX7rShTFkbexYDEHNgEoUi7bdaLxE7hQz5CWnnIGXoqj8LUNACqRCkcfa0FeBNuAABM3JxG7G5JkqJieZPPLaBTkOBozItTL2NWPgzWP3Jbgh0/TPoV6TrcQ60GArCrwVdCNM0COloocxBM0CKiEo2FtbrYbBrkF6DJky3qPYqBHSV1OzQVqm3QrSEoRAXML5VXkS7rBJBiXUoGEOMDjlnBqJGQLekxIUUQaHVEo0nehA@h33I02GO45sGhVgMa58xNlVoJ1DAxAjZCxQN6ym5dWFgvLgga@qrJXLwGygP4HYbMXDer0/fKKCpIbAKukfIhHVc048rBuxOOQXA99wbEBRAk4tV9iV1x1CjSP7jQSBgKySjZzsE1aU8zPrfNSaL2gbHTGQjLUO1CSr6cklCdp9XhvKq6ganaEq6P1RpCoyL8Yn0LeYl1yxQGURbGi6qPCWBSqhEo4hBoJXF5KIRxVuU4bemzR7QiXgJqjsXBo1AP1z0UEPBFFS6AR@pb1VUzkQrA4cDnu@e/ppWdRF7plqWHZxxqHnNI0eOa9jcNmP@@Tw0fHu8TfqC2D0rEZx3iFlZQt5bGpHY6Vjj1JZVS@uh2FMAT@ur4aNEWfDyJLwZoozDqlKkyY0LmOfnEfHn82TBDQhJAelAGb8zak0PAwoXVLDcLtzjTDrJBKQZBDFD8uUQ@bDDAyIOvobPj7PR2/fYuHNIzUQ7ohZb2RwAL5j6tD246noOaeA@V6NNm8RKS4ooJaNw55TUzikj88nqDDPI0NadIhlPjk62D8uE9iu4Z6bvZ5CQVKuB7qUMWypwPO9UcuUFoUB8QemJkuoU8RRlSZcFxK42Zwh8LRs2RL4AAB7N6rDlF7fz5rbBdz35vNGrkoz4ACyE4R5vTKsDzU/FNEQHtjENbGTu6gVJY9pYxU4LWyxAt/ZZquZy5mb2a1ws9WcptkKA@2TUmw5vt44BK9zV0EXdapFCrVaoH/y5BbiLimR0BVQfMzcHlMpLbcnYe9FsVjUTe1B58zpmepLkngyk@OpVNQf71SbLnU3Q@H3x5YXS8f5V4tDWEh9d/dQf@wHFmN0NHZBnQbsfWPLNGzj/ELTBR6xnZ7TcdgGxOHaoZ8gqE1Ls7nbcexbJWSgI2Y1ghMWIH9xqMYYQFtjvaU@I8UK91T5ZIdhu5cgpbV8BolEFCJQKQqvfmlcGECuab5PDr@5D42IlkunA3OaHiBBKA6RC03NkCs5MAUSUgU@CzMYTF7cqu2@hxKaPcBMC0EXRNydei90JImpphaGX4ASn1EKhUGFGtVxy4m6NASHMgvHPtwBNNo0dNTEEnCx2@8B5/NBGj6@4IE@jQUA3aoojooZLh97gEhiHsGPD3pYAIHG2ILxJTuYP4GSoVikekOXHFRvHATpTgcPUKEHjoMECSfsWIB0sGkssAMCFyLzjOzyjPCUyGU2S@fQ5bARWsNkBaVheXzozhkNcXzeaoXzBsEzOg8D0ChzoTKjgXzo4/PBEx6ZcgEKngHqPyj50E0AyUnDUSZlweCTAKjnuTj@BF2XtILjoQBfYQ/3uobdNHlfUOmjgsSUwT6LesPUrvLNlKG8BQZdITcx87vhOSkq9FOfADTKEExKUQ9IjG6Q5HH6FOgl9aXQ85HflEmDideFHCtNJhtlZ2Da8/oc1/Zi8RJNnUSj6peOZceuomtra9FitBJNgmkHTNto2kFTAkw7ZFLIhOFUNFGMJJnQt0ox0K0Wvan6kMfxGvLAGKXCW2sQM6rFYqaWNKqa@Or4jUNRAOUhtIIfgBONl8tojMflyiWOwELbHMr7HvLOSXNoDQQJvgaVndsFDTJEBFDdsaUemiXUO1dTpF8egkJoYvMRG0bPqumz2tnVWStxdhNNYux4ySiD7heD9GJ9tTN0RgMQytVsUdFq8Xg1U6yVGuVoOroRixWUHiRkxOMfF@IJg9M6FoVeZy92dhYFkgrqVJvdIcEbJ/V4PCAU4AE9iha0TbGoelWA9BvxWjwRhbjxaBL6AuVoFOjSRCK4lGnU9jkTHUDn0sXxZeixhocKSZjTUDNW12@ag@5kGA4Q9KihBcXRsen8GlQGmqEMN2xvefywsJ7R4v02jYeDhgs75igLBxMurSWO6VlqZq7XbxUulHbf8YzU5yooREEispuKrkVTipKSGflwSJTtp5aLVdiwTWfkhkcRFg5uYOrgetodgbD0J8KTwFXWQDKbXYdF1x8CdBaM3mKDgAPRCh/O9gG0mir8UIieHh4xHAM1bY9miC2Qizh7zHtcGiHBRY8/7pbLD96oQWolisPSmJDVsZ2hqQBJIIZE87k0@y9VmJgkPqRe7a0xR@G7B0mSUm2ZIBEPeo5BtOXiOjTMO@iH4oPuDVGOzZbUA/nRBvGo8rIYmq3UhkRzLs6wCy0E5AYlsR6UVl94pBx30FK9MUSVYqD0zHhyzQ3UykvW0nU938y1i74fcgUQuwuFhBqnDeqr76Vo4BkXhbzPu3y@/v3s6PE@7xelRu6QelbYR673ndaoBxzMdaJj0@4k2T7wk2U7fQvI4Md/e947dhyPa/BgWdbr4gqx1R/1DOrPzXe5VsZrOg2nR928VVGn4UdD1@gZvIPp@@5@/vTw2fMXpydltRgKlDIu@oIyh@FJAZoH8QdxXc5i8npOxhbIXymCAkN45NFjJNaJALV990109ysHjnQK9wK693GNCOj/Qtcna@AoAm5RQFw3gtPtwvFKS9@g@1JNKQinUbhLXEESwvZK08n9wmu3Z5wz5HyuoJDpTZ2z5MzXj8xocmGUcjwQLiaZCRMGlKcwwZqS@XBCDAVzgF2z54/zH4OKgWPZ0Er3UBGyzUscZ@cLO0y3iZrzyCZZiwPhrNk1hu6tzgXUjoHCQ0uRNeJ4aI1SqINI6ykmBqJKxPOg3PMJBJfLQQcUcOrjbFf4jBIwhjXk0xcpPkS2XgcQ25WSP92/LBimFI0GwQgq4QYxKJs0r3Yrq8EsqUsjXxJFKUluqvrqbKynlbPx5n4t5RIR2kw@Oxt/nNa/kJMMF2SsP0h1zBImt5RaZOejRc0uCACWGM@SDMphZLedXkvhQ9NQ/oAxjT27wVxgsCSERDe4WEN/NYiFs8xi1Q4IvtBCkltw54qucjtAaOlJAAhqwxW7Pk9eXLMqtEUXqjvoWV6N3aieU@9i5r3R0J5fpMKVw@HQmLiSmEous93jTz6vpmscgtQ3cLi5wEtr7K9xAo0WNBhcSgYmnBD3LI@aaJr5szC/mgpIjWlkEtAHGDyBEgsSEjlC1K/N62le2qYHSpSJmLuTfpKZ8Ru13TM8z7Q5b/Ex/@Xk5oOzIpkyJb8jRvqKLE3DoaAyWugHKJbYyenj/eNjFTjUjUX3cdi0CNXOaHZBc1iWaZ@S4cwX2cetKPsY48QZpgJVCroFdREfmLcEzA0dA0gdRUHHHMbAMY4jnk1wpkFmishVJ0EgXNbQ9IhGAbCYGYc8EbDiQvxf2LwPJPAssihLECWB3LEHRaCtFVdHtvVGdaGRIIUSgkR5L5LWr5XXYyS@1rU48c/Q6uOMDXR@SJ@DPFSrbA2kG4WWWfkde1VNK1u1xDqr1Up8Hg4ionZO6@HE2ipD0JMPWpOAFDgfiv5Ve26FnZ8Cja9gLI6fBjwrCb4FZIejxuR2LZXXdTkeIKu8BQfuKc8juWAFGEfRX3tAIoSWKswuOZhd0BDK1gvqLs@t3ITs@AgE@cHJghjPJVsrMy0e9zHjgF4aQ@wEF9lzx3WtRo@WlrV7Fl@qETTWRUEYAcmnTDi5ElYMohvWZ6hnWBjT9YR8lZ6gBPlTQwN9IswZOcTi7AqJSaTUkYrs@hodZLauM2IDGZfzcfre@L1TkI9PHED2iVieGNY5SGiISWQUHWeS7HfDZmdp0Ier@KmLOe1VuZDD8bj2aNnnDo31BqZ6WtVyqDEGsfvnvdsx25bbpddM0AAHHlZfhp3bb7TptSAADXmKyTRyoME0oStDcRqpY/rQuNqClGcnkGeSbZjtkd2hmQc0M@XNHSGVrQIFbjca1rKgQARcDuJ/FwQDWYk1T1ezqubXHhyqgWYR5Cfv3UyzPr/2gM3QHRopD2KJ73/5Vgvof7t0utBe4RhlYKiDpoAlpbSXFpaIihZ6LS5YPoc56lkGEYZMd4FsGkPIktELDItB0wScooC@0cfhRFHiwJv4Al10BZtxzPlsgP9dnMiiAXUb5HZzWdi5tRg8KRr6hY5fi4jAdS7LpEgkZHkhmGM@/BrqgqPAvRspf8EEI2bm5d4deSP@BnX4zkK0BvhbVTdFyHTOaGgmdC2NhmWuKPKhcT5qOcrgvBOoxfkFYae5p/kfBbQSMRVUR@Pi7PMMDq0ONPf@d1mwafuauqTPXVzh2iN3oDSol97iNqoI/RUpDHv8vSyIJbYRBIblVLN69LonJwrowChiJjSFS8yUENGsOTL3jMYEVaHuh3NZMKsIEqfcTCTSmSXTSoPB8vjYP6X4W1uLY4/VJqfHojGEFF/GpvBRNsqwWNh2R6lCc2X1jZ6it0LGpcJ80aTkraDBfAbFMS@g0Oi1ismxQWqOesZwalrB4lM8/GmGZSPWotkQdbnp9CwXK3RvmdT0V8ZM08KFhPQKzX5aiyjZgo4otuNKYFosBZymhyvGlrDVPWQaX6mF6@FCfKI6y4jVdC7xt1SD6EJnmL8XN2pvF2J1D/mk9Jo9A5rypS3CzPghjk/ewauXlmvSazFhzxci6jV7C91na4E/Mhge6buLs12r57jshN6rCNQZAhX4ezFPh2lpGbZC4@Vh8wox5E9xTgvU6HWcXr7QSRnwWlrqo2EbRb/43lfIBUJK0@4QUr4G5Nia@C4V7eep4fldBUQbNIa4vC1kXNHKLpJUYnpmee6gb4Bze4tzdpAuUEw1xccQlySMszKXxsT//gKtxzLS@q3HYEIaNSh4GGGrAAZvyLXsXyS17OrUWvcTSrfAbt6ViVDhnvdMaK/ofatImZ7WPjCGlk7fX0S1eyNzZC7saxw1vjRxj9@Kfsb9kUqLbKyLwXycP8BF6UGot6JzeC@ssalG20phYkCv3bxbm5kVagNQwAfYe34OhudouB2jY48GM6U600Gzj1eTrDvwq7TTmsEOfT5UDhXuUJZmVHTXpN/KThPv5OH6kHI2nU4LHSY0KTNjWdWZygRxv7T4eyZhcpmmPA2LE3HDkHFxGkSW8AqkpSJIX9a3p8BbWynbsk1vgu97StOG4/Q@pKRAqLYs1MZAuaSVdqtK7Ja6I9aQs@nohYtjHo32snEL3tqI7iXQB/vNqwo9PNd0r9JUcF4UqmBnzrp6BCc0c3VXKrjXEoeF@Nq73nJdUgyIaGpB3VxZ67iG6jTMnsE/43x2FbwtNbMS3qzQEPO5OP/LZ32ns/WROaE0mACxrBZ0VLpm3yTrCkXfaH05cv3P0kBjB3/LvMem2UyN983msgADC@SCje@ZaeaQsuQ5NnSxPGPYMbGr0sOFZMJ1mQT2pxMXEvmwb3RMvoF8laScjlngghves5saF49eFPkimyZEm44wL2cJqFTn5sT1vwsBPp00oVxH/btH3OYqfxOHQe9R25etYLvdxNpdp2t3zS5fNhrYllUO4EePb/hfhTpg3ek2GYmm8ArXMD17Tq93H3qiaOSC0nHaC3Hax21vuHHjg@BOjAZ4iM@d43eGx2UHGpbWmq45gnbJdTxnYCpkWxa0h2M9/L1Mhvqz37/oINLKrj5QxP/@ovDv7Ft2DMcbDOhTH/RGLr0oqkK7Fe/Sm9p89QqSnTnDjvrW6TdU4aiKpS006b5YxDQsr9nFXaKcs82O02h2rbuQbpiGZ1vnKX/Uh1vv1XdFylhMeYzOas8C8g4nKvJLOex/gp/DZYUuBpB4sxYYVugriwbpaEOmMjDOmy4fEEUTK@KYcKg28m2bRdrvWnwzsrwp0NByp2CEl89MoGEZ7mJZxlLNipZIT8WwWK6xlEtJSUeFXDHToPBoS8eXZpbChapYJsNfyxAK55IwCi14@RByi@VBNEBohYZuwX2Gv2bWNS1s5OzuqOPeFph8xL4FKhq@ForA3Q6e84Kb8Bzm9pxLWnRGW5ynO/lC49nQmhm2@CwrAL2Xwt1P8K2DNjYyV0645FbOuFA4racYjgWfOnygUEdLR9d61sDlb6a0l87TiYVQ0Eufn0zkVJss7maLImuZbT4/gqa7lMe@QzO4oJ0oTZztx@F1FPNcJeMizXY6IO6VHpsG9sMuU2gWrkxazBhBa6p88czsGLhQ@4nl4UrPBfxCzLxoRdOdsL8@Mlzr6yPI2TI2xF3cfI5yGN7zi7YF8J4aHav56UxBBEgKAotlovwzUzHQ6XZZXHYtF1dXBYYVQ1bIcpyJkevq0KNYEHJ@UD/YwD6t9Xx/1MLQiwbencEEt5FMyLRqzN3yaPxVfJd1KpetO1uJxOWoPxi54rMYB1q/FR6f7p@Tu3tpAXDlDQhd1jV63uIx7NBgLOhnormcGpfp6d@0ek6HfbOQZqDOgXqGavsCxnkEDfdzXDQ0tBdwIqV9zzlRHAJRuOxz30DZmhmmWLblrR7n8TxcQOR/MTO8TcHtDakn@FYffigE5XQxRZ7c3QuY7lm8o@UHzjtxRsOmicbgIIJwh0Gkau75S5dFq2Gbl@H@28p5HWgoHXvkKcORvbJVyK9sFYpsXMiH2IDFvr7/9EU8zA201Psu/dSEbuHI7U2mpqWrCeaYzLJBRVsuR2dD@72Mx/zIlGNaZ3xHnF0816VJ4vqxs6gn9HwyNL17d6VA@I/6j80mzinemfYz56ljO9AaDUBQ9o9Nvhl4ZhXI4ogY7QludwX6tO5M5oTALmmEuLZhDMwGlG9varpPW8QBPzY8Y0lTRKOG1DMMTHfyitVrmMMvaTgwZF7W2Z1F6FNzTL2O5QzD66DiNZtcWcaRupk6MjOX4w4cx@ZvkrZp@GhPV0sVaArodf9ZdBVX8c@MGCzsuc1m9eiCLyExW3y3@rK8Ds2G0@PvFQuWbIsvGDCGlummnuDmZ3LLZ5kC2pe7UoZsrpQh004TaLIXhksz@Is7IVOQ2vgD1gd1jWHTwTkyYVixdCe0Y/kOMR1sDOCrChpA@DFILKM5Esem3YVWr9/o02tpVyJUmsdmA7cUNWibv2eMbxcmHzMSe5xDy72CncG@uMJKnWex59BPid/dbM30sGapag3oRZJ66UQ6reRRbMtsvjVwPM0hek1HrWf8Ic@pZ2RcMoodqkY0vpwyaAvswpo0u64NFJqeqXjdoQnKr7dq4Ns/f2HBTMmob@L08@z8zFLV1XG7lFln8Ux7IFyHpiKO/QJZEhwBxvVDZXep5ong4f/o0ddS0AjX81n/TAIQXXfP7QPyo6EtPvfhwOeO67Wt8RHgjTsSlokTzFYOosCH1ww0bSzLBJSePerxcYlOaFFWv0XdMYWOnVSUHolrz1RM@0KhE6LGt3Pk8B1jqV08x9AzW4rYII1zEMoTf/NYEEx8F0ythmUjrgTVUpyw43xWrA1dRNxLXzKAvuV4ysClb2rgPj98cnSqDlxtca@/izs1bulxMzuu9UI6NFj1pTEMzYTytWoty/VSj040Ze/JoYoBltCbz3Uo8ME5u5nP0hFRcWqgkTKW9oLQ1/QWK4ifnj59kpju72Sxve7Q6ZvxsPfeyUkSd7187WShdzj2AdSOtjNeGv1wX9PiC9j3hU3zhsuk54KUlkE6NaE3Csz4KT@w4U7lqukMzNbpZGB@Do0nSnD3nsnnl2bymXFhdbAWsq2lhKKKyrbUfDYeWrYNnW1zGHyXlee5NUBp2aRPin@WLlRBzSGTGmYWaw@r1gLMazEsLdYofFgkLX2bWz1LgZrR6aIpZbh/X8Q0TVtG5xOjDeXKcksLazbAopnjnnNxj0lmU3RelMBJ8YCrFOvOReabSh9EdwpfOHAvHMHYWLpAZhWAwDm/sMJfmvbEsBWa5VqlXhQhNi53Wxnkm@Y9pqqCtT8XeJbrwtm/YL09izXJGL8j4dNhKMre3qPDuyIcC1quDvXJsxfsueE2jd4dAcMYm3djzDd5HI/s8OGAblJsAed7s/huGVf1T3CMxYxEIh6fPR84vDeI74ox8HRo2tACYa@v2ZrYtwIewVYesVsGz1uGptLEPWaSD6LK1q/E3pJiUbvB/TVyUWZi709w6hY/Oaq8HsMzbwBVPBmdrfubUhideMquGTWXUD@1XBpsaiq8S7AkduuwIiT5/PD5/snp7umLk2q6diPHxZ40jpZhQEL@bsWPMy0ZciMIAa0YP0KOdrX1IDk6jRWbWdfPEoNMzeWqPJOraX7kHYyzfmUYqRRtzkopN4CfIvPUyBfqFDpx2H6OieJib12R72nqETXldQ5apjShFIosvSjhgeG6kC3hP38eNPmyTAZ9ecLi1C9gso7jtESKrsnufvwUD3YPn7w43mc@glM2uLRaXre8leGHwqESr5hQTm2L5nnLLCqiRKGsyuXoQRQIE1WjrEhb4uhANuBcCOZTBzfTidgbLLZO8IGC0aBQUv/lW6mbqIpLluIQNuojFWWC8hiAneI2lz/73RY/sNTfpu4feD7sk4pIm4glsYVtyQY2pChVtcHyY8/pgFDaqxacTDo9Sl6io2qBKy9Rc5g/fSROBwLwM@zF4TB@QsQg/iGH2MPFg15APb@wcKMax6GN567MsjJOlzHc3KuyXTzTHXgeWB@RANRHtsfPNhD7pyPAR2ogIpJsnZDlp@vKoYDR7TVg5YbZsWzm2qA2mF6RQU@eepFFvltSUSrRW1F80Pwwf6Xr9XuhgLcOanFTZ17q/a99L9UpMTCP04/A9ivC1gbzr3LzqxSW9e3DXKbph5EwsdZxrHniAc2R3qHj622@K3VKLDxzxpd9zOpD0VwQpTE4T4G/FZvJUzix6udQUMBiUEpiNypPzxzWYl3PGxRTKWQjHJFXaQWeOebT4SoweerNCE/pdmw3lc/ls1oKkFQufIB0LGMHt/pwgPF4ERhfurAG5dcNYK/tbSZjK2SW8yVemql141VGfh0gug5hpcsuIldlEAeiTGOAX0VEgwYiocUxKsqjqBZFUdRyoOUgf2xh0G4LQsgsBsTiNDLxnL8x3mPgDSc4UjHqtfDAINsJHdm7LgApGjQ/ZIrLkthA@czxgGVmto7yDZS4HIS3Ujh56vJ7OuhgceRB9XZtmu778c8GFvVLxXrPQWXS8w1euGzllwjiBEEU5UUsW33Fzrwzu5bivMmATX8sWDbMzDaYfznVWcKzPN@7t4@Ris0fAoXEYg9PbAcH/w4gMyymp/RMSsvHp1nKZhdmSeRIJAPZwS3x15AciCYQE03T@tIZuLt7@4dfO3p@cuuoJAoZnQ8GkryynThT1GS1Fhii4WzNFsmjg9TJ00cHfkFMkc6HJDDoIyIn2qqcTLVoBDldrzmftUUYzuduOcYv@aaueXwz@irUKNItPLT0B6RLa6aUA1r5PJ@4XlhErVxuFUpTeKkQ6D2@beUWqrH41U21tl05syPR25ywoCK8iqgbWAnAdOZurKeQ2W9nDjMW3KdzircBuOG6mFlcF@X1DJ7zgRvnPOd8esKJcAh5hPLrJwMiUlJTftClte@I69HTE3V0ft8PPxEkfA5CCOF8ehXFQ6BO/auDUIpMzwMTR2F1DbfbsxqSf/4EPxLLP7knOA2Lnx0Ri0vixFiecExcJjQujlWaBo3FUdoRrCRbdbqWDy8uQYVGfe35CLpuz50BP0GQhrsfm77p2AHx@3jE581M9rVRH8K16XNs0tADSG4FIgMlowGqXH8CKSEO1xon8PgySK@KR2yJjKv9Vi42jqtdc9yyOiDbY/EkSLSPNa3GggO4MNN04JYdlanMpqWwsip@gpuRwmT/oFPYxlMEjKqhWtBXH8eil9F4sQbpo3v08uVFNC4v4iU6DU4cj9aaPxYuQH9TWy1JDE/UTv/MtUXSYmvrtpQAt3nA/BQU//jyrS2160p0AUUZdfETb/gEjKBGxNp9Y8BiI5ufFKMyssbOYnaSjtZQKvzYKJslEtRFgg95qIxitsnE2@@YYU9YLFUGJkBX127h5601YFVNVWtgpkTibB2vFdgDjQtPXYhL0E@FKEUCW0YWgo4DYMQricoZHOKgv4SHYQzpvJ0F3nTKOg3eOUgTyjWrPGChiyFmNUd5a6soCnRWKm4x4L7b4lBNAdhbcs7X5YG6Ylc30Aw6tKoUmQry2xIvQulGOCKfiu3ggE4kdNSbv0ucAazpQWzN7hB/sX0b6goebFF8cXpQL8RTMgu2lXeGVgtnVuiYtkjQaRNnR0M1Tc0EjZZ4H@0TjIbnBdX5vnU8zuaAKow8J1IjYTLMX5E25U1NW8n1IqIoBQiZxQZArL2v@@DwYCx/LmeB32Jh//Of4yVscmx9J5@p9y4S0Vy6BC@tlGM59vH6maKsV/VcuvxwvWYY3pnMjFR24/GF2W03DjupM1lmGZZNpTb0/JvzgZbfeFVV34xrcrVQTp7Xnp@z58@/eFd/F5fHFxP5LMY2I2zv6FrWIAOR4ibbYvhb@NANSQufZV10OQpAWSRydoaXq8mbcipVjdbgn3xfw8PDVStqRd2pvXsXr25CnsaTswjeW8SOHs7Ci@l6/MSyrBQ7G7itFvycLqvxW/ci/EkkYgoTDkqVu7H@uE1u412z0xntGxPubkVG@DnwRNyn33z58iUaXtLD3h6L@Bw689Mo1o1chOlp/c9@unaTvHpe3/6zb/dT5hp@jvDzvZunaD7Rch@vrX386FE2mwQqcfPzbz7/xu7ubvZxMve8mtvJKum17T/9k7U1Xd/WU2s119Vq0er5@Reyns7K6p/9JFp//vzrrovFgk@GaWDEdwF@GupU5@wtPOdthv9kftsKmQ00N9pvmR55GwG2jkzorx5hvBaWSUsKP2tMq@xs/tcfHL2JeJGKnno5hK8XeRPJFyLcCAawZXzbRaQS2cZg@ZvIJFUul8G4@V//HcSvfA3goM9kG16VnA8rP4lUlDJFuY5U8mDQdB3S/b@/9a1bXPSwCo@c3dTlnRo8G/RsS3h6j5JOpeZCa4UH2gPGbK/rmQ5@LP6x4cOMkg3d7ONqIpGoqQo8ap0ipTRNP6MRmjAv0QBLJHAuMe7CQm5TxhAu4PcyQkwEXESMxM3CgXiLO7ycD/dywVN6@Y/zHEuR/NpD83GlAhJPr@gblQQ9a2fFItG8nmKbBdlxHuLAVfRMjrLX7IkgcUVOF3Q5mUw@rOPNlWyMlFTGkSnZGKcMi8zQM8KmNhZ2ijA/GpuG@dBw@/j8@f/@5z/88x/Q3w/p9x/xeCO7ZbVTG9XYRrx2Ua/wh1UqcmUoX52R5SFLFwvFQop8QR7VjpmW/uQ6mstET7At8B9/IDMSPJUKvnw00FaJcJcKN03dhE8lsFCIaZTF4ZgQQD5RI9DSirUeSvWixip@hhY91YdQTLK@uSXXKnpOP4Ki02QquC3WXXeZE/FztAPPGvzRPzw7OEgsXPC9Ro7ch4IueNYCZO5@5jGVItVINWXWsG0IAj1cK64Vivminqqz5YBKy6BHLsJiRN1UC6oOgkNh1bVjzu81lvCfs8SdzwtVrQsjGRz8KYozjkiRf4SnIrHIFTy1dxvVdxt1P@mqqKuJbaVWSQiM4KPWH9YSys1NVX2VKJXE/3YlMJboSZQYGiEntRtF2X4FwKqzYKNZJ5p3HiJ0Dpzeav3VNoBPbFe3y84e/VSqLUrtVaW6PQtCIPfwYQKl7EMAUFmvsXgisa4oa9WleQCAtRiDDgAU4M32TeWmun1zs70N/9v0vhFfcL3ZvvVPn@mzJMzUv4aMdlZNVc5SZ4JtamBXUxV0UVNnYKjAF8JBAyRF3kGrwp7yhz21bfiHn3CAr40Pmmzy5HYyPPUDCWfuIkU2GDOL2oaeSeXGH@f3QY@q1hTs7pSVqpbP1UiTkSLX2PBDhd2SIinsHmzxXsIWuWyBwpfaYBuRAdM2M5ENkA4uW@P@UgTyCQCuqH69fv/V/4q/s/df/T5rvMG/J2/x742Hf6dN/Dt@g3/s9C3@HXv497SBf89d/Dt9g3@7Dfw77ePfozf499TDvxcd/JMiZVDV1nfWd9K99EVaO9fOwWCx9JClu@mu1kI5mjZZepKesHTf0VpgMuEvDSYr3WbpDkvbaVvTwBMMHkt7aGrDpwN/bYAyhD8rnUbg6QsGqfRQOtMx//S9rrP4mVRl0dcmaJmqpqbVvFWv4fnJoH6WIqmzsxTvSDM9W8JjlG9u6vX9Z4/r9RTNx5w9dY6m/0dH/bB15X//yHl65PQd@D86Onp6BhpKJfEwoTyEp1xJbIvPTqRS2jkrKsj7fjWLpLZ3zioZBc35BNQcHd0SH/hMIcK3snYmRdklNPmXJVInSpcXpcsSGQLry1IdzH4AEYwbwLEk1BBwgXhnL1OkQVzCc0FwyYbGS/D0TdyQenl5hpo0dJGCf6BH2PoP8G/9f@v/6QsWq9biUAeubrZj9MTxLx6/urm6Ee9KPBYTltg2/KED2DHK1U0FjRToCkzVWLwWv7nhbvCOxbc5wAqmsV2hyNOAUNkjQZqULn/F/mG/mLZ4zvBo39Dc9tnZOJ2Olxr@UaI4r2Nc0xRjvERXPKw3qlrtT39CB8buxClQLlsqaRuMW/SsXiplfdtmoVQq@Jb1WGzr9lNJ72h50BOy2Xi8VALLjg82DdYAbAHA@pYcQDVdo0m1vxSJYya4RIil6ZBlPHk/KhflBw9i4rauncEg/uCBtpW@vg6c6vWWNazX0T1zfS3XZZpM3sqBPV24vgZhFI07w9gzvJ4BwMYUjX2sVyiFLWcIOd0Eb6al9GmaXcM1PG8Ye2sNkjIuQnTlOJ2enk47w7Poz77/7W@fRctlWZHJNashAEyF5ba389lKJZ8Fc74ApJDXr/hFAp3Elha/WU/JPLtMXo9GhJdW2IxzERhFfxbZZjsVqMEuPuzqJkLlyrK5eKwxMeNX4OK7aVtb3JFl87FCYkv8ldfirAJtEv/D7lsmkd3Y3HiI/bfxkgfFbunKLGs35SuziMNeN6WmuPQGt/6YDx5ktoCghXTpTKrXH@@e7tbrZRmaPxlv2GDoSAJcwvs4BsNolUaGclu1KmaudhaNFksPqei1Qo5FoiURTolCS8AKW0QDyWrjvj7IOMJc/nv@ZHdv/zSpb0MbrR/s7iX1kxePIhpac1M7eWfQfry/@/joBUR4/mR/92T/k8PP9188B3eXXU4fX5qK9/QbNi2wX7KX0pfDt4ZpGubINOuXo9HlG/alZdUtIGNvZFmW0xky16ybpjmAYP5Tgl/Tco0vvzSGA3rY@x9/9/2P/9v3v/3997/93fe//cOfffXD78Lvd@H3ff79/r/dyuH7Z1/9T7/z/rd@Gxz/I/z@CH4//dlXv/Et/iP7H8PvP4fc/lj8QuH4TwJYv/Kzr37wk5999as/gt@/Er8f3f792k8X/374neU/jPeD31kd5vv/Dn6/x2H5Yb//W9wNv7fC/xYP96s/ev/r/57//6n4Q@Nvv//1P8aXsPyzH/3pf37/7f@g64U//Tfvv/v999/5wfvvfPv9d773/jv/VH//G/9GS4dfv/P@h3/wV3/4e3/1h/8j/f8uvX/vPv/vf/TP/uJ/@4v/4y/@UPx@Cr9/D6af/sV/AJ792z/4Mf7/4A/@9o9@jP//y7/@2z/4F3/7K/8zGX6TG/6ff/Vv@fuvf@0//c2//N5f/fRbf/Mvfvo3v/kHf/V//ur/9Rv/6a//u9//6//h2@j4mz/9qz/6lb/89nf/8jv//C@//dWS93dXvr@6h/tX/wgu98fzPnDuk68PdfnqF8Ln70ONaSrAJ8Dgv/z@N34JePzXue2/Bxv8B17fCywzPtzyvakFIPzLBZF@@Wdf/fOfBLZfCgJGzOJso1HQC4kNUJ03trZo4M/3274NBZL7HlbKmRS@h9X5/Y@/9f4n//T9j3/z/Y9/BQW3kt1K7iYVbfXiMug0Kbl7hMOA@fuEw4CQ/BdfwGucoAEzJYE29oUI8MUXX0jj6xT0X9IPr8H1C3LiD@Ne4MeEl@8n3HFZYjgMN6Z94zo6X4eTBrMmBnvXJJ2@@JK0BH4Ta2ACfDekXAZshDr6bPi5SUg5zfeICFjcc0yD@mP4l7JbLAKRxuPEGHo8YEiMWQK8HiVYuVymyOUxBQUrxhmzSgGCj3FQpozQIRKPk6wXEMT4EUGBmOXEMatvlMc8YgLhVQgCIYdOx7Kmy4lC@TEkWB4/ZggLgRPY16/LlUJ5XEFw7wgFSCjxiHBCYOXEuPIO7GWCCfGkyON3gEqhnEhUCpggZpLTKlmnNLUcZY7ynmCUb3RntNpy5yFjH8taQSyJXEOC8dD4TkxD79CUxw74nyU2RHbo3zfSb4MIvkZJiVR4sWBiazy@CABwFUVVVQY/RUFsHoL3mINKULLwSSREsQI8fHyQ4MCwP5@QElS@CbJA@pHyxgc/iQr7gIePXBbycj2hTXTQSuX8Jg5d/pNbz3/zTxY9i13xkThN19fXpUhFzshHNAuQgI7p8LzID9G/5l2BIpPzWzI6m7QcmNPYXH9OneuNxxvw1uB/f41W6SZYiYizHsVBnCjjuWYfJ/jv4cMN9jGUAX2nbhJTEhkni0OxSO7tRELWIdWKk5BegbSToBIRoGtJHZdp7iEhJZOMqeUI@rGjoyOBGjm8KksJqIN6RkM7DhuPRqMIxFDVpAo05V@VvuSgCoNKvuKrrmPJ08VcTNezJVDySwydWFgn16Brho7v3r0DlqGZ@uIh9KCYmLTXswXyBAe@m6rXm/jLw/XslsR7jEzL88soY3SfVZzFJRZDLo9LfFUnRyOYBYzqhUIUTXEoFTW24a/iyGtSpGmiEsukp27nkTOGrlxSlpNaHqc04zQ0xqTToo7CS9ovpuH9DadYLL/TspsSfMk@Yni4Cd8JBRUIV82q29uMcl@5UmjwEI2Q@7xUqYjVFEyTKif7pxDh9Ihpelpl0BG8ym7q2Vw2p2fy@dymrmXzW9l8rpABgZ1P53Rd28pmtwpbmzeMvVZZUeEXoWmFfFzFWYu6067jiUcqey1VvmBjFXJRUm6kSq/cM@2O113HRQ7yWVou0aghkWG9mk7in57JwBuSTGq5zdraWu9KwRycEUmvcLUKpCpdKcCz7CN4mPSRxD4CJ3ggDVyCwsT6n8OjkliEgZuSY3wlhqzloGrEpTNAlIOTBuGnNGMbACdeXV2FflJk7Zvf9FilAp025fBAioDY6TJ/VYJitdSuSrc9t0Z4yzv4dhhrWZ9beCGB6l/NrmfSqhS5ublpA6TDA5zLIiuP0cL3TZNcGmC@GRvS///8gz3b/MiOCi4yd4xWObgZHSpp/KpVbjlNuqKk1C5Xa3TjTKmlNpzWRHW9CbC1KMRytNFzmudR39PC29xwR1M5ZaTUeh24wHOgr1@OplLRHX0zV1xLDVMqnVDEYm2o2Tt6fhMcz2zuGmuDSw5dXs06bRVbqo/UU2BZiKcX9XzuZluc21WBPCFqFUTkSuBXtB3bvMHl4UWjDVLsqsnXABVlPVeQS9XS1L6Zl0u1m4d9s2UZ7CyNS4KvFkbM5@UbPxwkbUJlox0nsT7ek4EbC4rps3R8SeQ0RAaUCVNpWxwVUqE1LVWQKTW89Lda2/YPEalITNJ1Rc8oGU3RMvh/h0HH//uH1@FfxzfEyujSKR4Q8wyKG2SnzZ7gaaaew04dhy6ueWQ2l4TY6xq0eGdv6Lju3yPMI8M@516PLX56ReD1qYEnVrt9y@suCfFi0Me9TubwHw3Cfr8BCCIP8gCP4DXsOc6iAJvsxfMluXwanBcFxOAHRkHw48NPPj0NfU/3d/c@lfLs0dGzx3OfnAiUY0/2D04D6yb39aPmAhDf2H/yZN4qPqBmlGjcbY3lNn2DJuHqvwfQDXggjLn81JhG40u@McVyg9VofAdSUTr1d6tQ/bAaJmvy7Wdjacy3LAu1QNvckqQBs51LtplmLafXM/DSrvYaOHYNXIVvYmveo7vlMOlLZ9hrQRUz16SnuOB/S8ObiRAJ6VMA0h81aX@g5Ul4AEYLr9PCwdsG3u07wivrljjCB53QOLQ6XY95l44fQGoYBoPfhz4Q3ww/3moHj6dBbrd8ereDSxHJ8IxIoQQM692UWvZoS3vwQHs@BAavFNLF4ln6Bjis/Oi8ODDHnmsO3P3xVhb4jY3YC6gBxrApy3oRpWUihX1Ltv7X//J3c7IMOh2T5TwpetrGAcsmWV2tR4wNLI2OVUlBi4Djs8esAOVOx6MwCTl4IwXCKqLJMq1CTEsqgdC3CrnCVkYvJAtbhWxOy@dySU1Pgv65uQVKTloraPlCbktLFrJbmSwoVeCb29qUInztR2qDQMK3CGDtJl6ls413EjlqtyJF@Fg@exsz4ixiBPYRk02II@M1qNDU4DanDass61kG/W1QrwGiwZoscnCwlz44kOVHaMEpyL20LLfQkiuk05uPZNkknz1Q/HRZdnicAu47lj1uSacf7cnyiAPAI7tkuYuW/Tz24mXZQsve7sEBptNGi47xIdg59@GWnm/ZhGA2WjIZGgaQ5TcBOAi3yxPKEqb7aME00eeA@@yBnyx/4uOTTgOEYx6OQ/jUz@vuriwfcsvuLvrsUcZzHNXP0LJLjywPwQK1Q5Y7YOhgmyfLDTBiHZHlJpiaEwPc8OIiPNfJ9gxZnnACIYlkeUyhjea5LNd9d0zm008/Nbpey@zwZzLkX@DNQ/CxxqP9g8YnnzQ6ncZwsrv/yTH67O19arQno2Gj0xDRGnV4HIgDPuf9yfwDOB7W60Zvoc9n4GPP@dQndRNxqxtvACfxdDCRfn0PfPbAZ9FMCIcGTx@CNvB51IfvI6NBPv5DPvQdNxpyCRkVt2bT7YNQZ@giwGTfaA6dEtrH5TXGorFoclLNp2sl8mB90NPSpRu6djBG9zZjdxA0qqtJdVxO18rj8qbOJ8rbMflsrOcsObnW39G2QAkzdjQ9mxgXcbuj046yqKLtxLQHG29jz0DZymSL8tnOjiJXtdqOrhWK@c1XGyNZjhfxvZPZLL6F7lkU@mD4ilc3azug2U2jbG4mjJRe3NyMl26AHB60oY2RZ9brsdilaZzH44gudksgC/zSwwnl0yq1Y@PkuMyxYpN4aVzWSvzIEZa@BauF51uNmp4z5BA7AG68ky7StYqytlWQIf1UKhaPg2QiIQLf6SqSl18/PT89/QJkFvQIRXfpOb@rqySsn3y6p0IPStjwXCr1ABVlZ6juoWCZ8eHHJvlOpyB01U@hIQSl1XfDBehDp6fuj6Gvi9q27@GfNqKKMyLU009n4JxAX5GnjPv3SrSh226aDI/tslrMKFfAZLRYjLBiRvySmuB6pVKul/v8ZsRKEOszfkn0FMyhy3EPdhVS9CtclC086uX0zTT8s1GfPeKB6KZXP1q9/Aja9HTJxuMqTbSus3FkLFVaeKLXo/Kjq1ERBxluSmbZxBsk5Qju@d2xyyPbNdrmc3OIm2gPj9ZZm5mvm7ic@/UZ3TW5h@r4jVIZMnsGj5ihVBrxWaeQFQkX@zooIpwiV7SzAKceb6BjE3sVL70B23CdxVrqo/hOtgQkfMTqLA5u6dft122ms3y2RBfwsBgCg1pGxKNrHOPlymcAm4M@LxYBF8EE5wAW01qHboHVIh8jPrBuSp1yFUNf42tbkeWaolSva1KlJFWg0pYmEaPsjhp04iNLNzQ9nS@NwU3bzJa6rFFuvBqXhuUBdKtZqQflLsYS@I4JowTUAzoBnLfXLPb@l74V31ZyZe5YImDXPdAjoDUvj6eFlClX9Ww@qeezOPSQz8BPS@oZHRc@J/X0VlLXoJ2G9hviw28T7Fn4QRhoxnUNByhivZjMmJxMj9OqltRMLQn5Tr@2Wq/jyfMYKCNEs3jSc/bx9kpwQBYCtiUrfI14Qt/oxVoOM7YVYmKQIyXKp5HssoEFL4RzbBo9Hj6usMxGrLcew0Drp6PBfrVWLO6PB18Hr5jyZief2Ewn3sbjpRgIz3jZNd8QlVHsEBUGa8DUYtyFuaN@Nb0G@b5S6soNFLe3rm3qxepovapokMH0dWdbrsg1KK4bJrQclCZc0ZmqKlM3vO2YroFl2pZeklSaoeYBpYGQcEg0FjuT/Y1BsWh0U49G49ESjlmuySxeElKS3xQL8jX6QNuRQWmSi/KWjgGm0vEWMpEbCbvBLLslRa6km6ub7fAo7mdsMjESim99wFgnsS6xFK1BAn2PrZFJUSs0rr1b3u0c74qLoNnunhQpMhZawS2xM3E2QWqNsQ9d@JTYrrzi3zNcXgipSnROTJXVaLWCaWEHin2Ou@R2WBSyZQz7VV3P1Kr6JjSJIGb9oLquldYTKRbB9YtqBcrDvZI43WlNXWo7UUmdSbJMwkcsHIkVcqA/8uXqerBcnYXmrSJNEzL8LsJlwd6VP2BSxOPIY0aRV/xqLf7umdW7KmQU3qcHYXRzQ2Xir/z97LWeg1KyHd8BOjYeCHlosXI5HJWLpF4P3G/qhczTwyP78fDA9MfTs3W5EmFpTcFFtaWicM3xUXZ5q6DL@nkywh5GShF2rkS1Iq0WZoOTrVebrwqvnr44enF0IEXO1q7XHBxGZX5psnf2174OAaOZbJSxs3JkXM6WxAqTSkXRtnW2A4Kd4YW/bS2vpK8rnIEr5JHXwef9L/0oO94ugF0HpbUIxZBL6JWKtqGzeGTw/qvfxy3bV/uf7z5hUdeYsL/7k5/om3/3J/@alm5Eb0oujQhuRiAkGrX8ZuTqanB1dQMP98tFahGOVHYzDma@LkiLTJm6mDKMjc1EVn9ol1IirLapxSOuEhHD1Zu5iHstvPR0Abz2jrhNzufkeGT/2Mrp2sNtZARtESOY7lZEihSevr5mDCzNSqvTsXQypVKs@E5h2@@UbfYOB5vfKWvsdbmCE4ga7nbwB0w3KpUKQmHRSiK1EWV6DvyqN6VagtGAK/TvXpkb9sbZ7LTK2Rrb2rLB3XQ3XOG04UK3bMOmP3PDdcHq28yNL10mx9hGPJVqtWj6attkuQqU/EYK0DmLv/@l39D1/N/9ya9d16/rX4C439raymt65Ofaz38OAVbsq/X7WTS2jBtg0RD0z9iSaynVJnQN6d56xsP7vTXsnzHQAayODV1wtEkXqNhQydT5YS2tGAXbwG13SVKT6SiFeEmSAnWS1OBhp5kkGGwDDwaGKildSR@hF7SWrAyiUvpoCorhleK9ntOsu73RcECD9jGKp9WS7AFEgRQ@wpNt1sTN3yRvFa2Ea3dvReUou0Q1UnFY33RdPCcHWgbpI4jyBBiebhtiAwN3tmJIywYBr2IQwpM8WlVIuwZp93iEOrnGKPc8QJJx7HgkG1Rl6SNo7IkKFigBzNqGACUQKR8BASAPMQHYqrFtlomzKyuRKE0P4bnBBZ78wm@x1U3CaAgNr4MPIpcwHDiBio4XCiBfiBIGjSvk6APhMPjsXBmUfIxONlSiaNvrvUEBLDpiIkZZYw8eTLEql61WnFGOEP65NcCBJioHezGuAMzvHn3cKspJZicSWNgfzbIdUDxB6ALXKfxco1IoKpPReiNJ8H9vpkWOnCsq8ihhBkR58VrRBJJBZCQ7L8Mm2y4zTd@MswD5JuDeJKToAJ6gz3c2/ljVv/A9bwDDn0f8QzklvOI7NHgn@HZ@WyWD1m6EJyLi4RpcGIjtkPz4DJRih54fO4gFWbF6FJpfDU@zg/5ZPLGMFsdo07OLCA9av6lnGS6thNYYPhQLQzP4GnjqjEhnjUbcmw4UqDtwbDqmhrbU47JU4AiQUeK0D472yL7EE3RF2VDkMEYunfSBnI8Y07E7dCkRxcUZxcYQuq0@bZLM7Kis2W8xfYvFiNHoVBI7ABenSIRww8QDooZOo2f2AaUT02R4UotbTKU6oNOMGnQ0y1ML@Kp7YEFTYrspcf9T6tI6t1KneAKg4rRBKxYbXSOoBmH145OX4hiUnuOcs551bvIx2djMNmGX6fkkKKJJoOz0B4Qt4vCvnkmyNHgneSj4bcJnkxsLyVDctdgkfvub0dZidSzRa2qTrCHe7XRh2CH60nMtiT6tO3H9gwZouzzY1UDkmmKLcTmKuxuDvfOSODKhTLv1VRyXH8RAhfOPGkCjNBiaFxBC0SRsY0BoNv1Nu1iLIbcfUQNAdQ9qFp465A2LuNUcMBm2Yk2oekLA2@xjltHpont@DoQ4swFgYNGXZ6GDH0TFfLheCwpG5dPBIFegdvZb4Id7HgX7YXyfu9FMJ0JN2ZutCXDY6FBaZcarhW/JhSxYO5CfKetr4JkHDBdgshaTEwA2IcdlDjqIPx@dc7tEsqTIbkNKMoQgSA1QSFXwL39joaNuJfB4ZLj83DlxPtHl5aVKB2WNhpZqunj8q4s32qUGHQu0YSflmf2BuGjDwquXBNypSeGnPuM9hztjumFw68GEfyWp7ZbFfvNYtO1GsXG8wNNNO306YANPtnCJoQ4sOhm5GaN5alfwn15LXvn8V0T@UwrRGwTCGIIZJyfJZhKAJRvN82T7slUSHhdUIQE4lKLpO@K5dEPf0nd9kzVoByEcj9aI@/ZG77zp9BzUSWQ@VjpNmufQDznxrcI@sMYQyTYv2e5waExi5B/H0MjAsQmpPWwCzT75gBGaGXbFT0qzxtVJbSb6OIgOjVowNTzE0zOkq9VA@bF56D/m/mPwH3P/8TRRP9nquMZVMnS6wewg1@OhS35IBDPxw9zwI@amPgQZFGumcRAYcjLjdgO/Zpli@/TmNijHss8YwBMDILgZS1VfnVXParZrXm7UEqkOMLtMhIASB9DVGtH0shWYkfq9i97AcWecbDxrC1olgTc6NbuCGzivYB6DAiLG4PSy8HikTl/lQztcIRAZBgioh4Enqga7XsyKl4KDF8kTGKcqT2nMEasKZGqkfQkv4QbqEic9J2wYUC0ECN2DLAGa4MP8msMP@/alw8sh3nbqh1XofOI@HtMRrUWBknNVhcuaEhVSCCtF8dEEsqO6Wp7Piu8PRVGd8wpl80aUfxj9tQ9Gvw31YjH2xLC8wShJ4apijk1Qq01RXYiqrFIOlStgkNoweuYQWq59rp@K1hqS2Uj53QyeDmbBvcS7zWKhwm/GefnQthzZlosBK0zKZcjipMyrJa8XPkk5wYNorog28RlBxOcCBGCkF0YzRbRxONq4XOaCg42XRLsMITkmJMc8Cg89XoJkTUSD3lNwKSYWTw1vbwdNSwZ4Gm9GQQ0ayAwvOMPp5y/xCCGclhRpTmUOcYHgIVSxkc@atYWpV0NIh4TWHABkxFsAWvzekKI0L/A0JbAFMoqT0pdR3CbYgMsKYDASwSV@zF4sYDLqA4PCLyeoHYC6KyeqkqzhIjL6S/OfnPQd/Z922zE9G1KbdUwn5/7@URxrSNlQBQ1pH1o6iwIZezIvxFWwMzpHBK/Y6jqg1TUuHRZboGyDe8q/RTbV6DmNVN/AJR94m0Bwt2zc7z/g/AZ7OHA8w3Oy2SLvNFnEdovS530Gq2M70DUJH68Jul7LMV076kGhNp2ObblmEm@z5Sq7SQsQ@Pm8UlhPFkbHlSQx9Mi7sQia8xWquvU63m9Ur8dcs9eOF4NDctGqIntGoxL2f8EUig/iSQA9GsQcvKfbi98NE0@CFdFOreZ57GggPKOQyC4DGdYE/R98u6DBMNeZ9hzpTEpUpRtejE4n7jp9pwNa38hVJYw9B/5wChsRMgYDwiXJDOzSFkNHAVMtiTWTRlxE/eyDo7LP9JgRD@LrswBmiJFkw3kaI2WHC5KrL02OR/PTO/lwfE/C@J6sxpd64fM48655mXt@WNKZ2BQCBJyikbkbDcw6yK3WLXRmUAmcUa/iEe6NYouWVLUQ010IuiuCq23gj2Rgc8EWIP75MvqvLkA/@v59i8/AS99OJiBv@rjSL0bnc7v@fGUMgh/GUfbcTi5g7cf3TAvC4pH9B6hCgBpLgsvG4/SgYg6g2@0Ghzz7gO/geVwZdYvvablUmXsuwGl4kWTn@vIielxvmT1jYrZiImQyBNfP8TF02Ehe3S/jKOhI6Dm8rxeDtise@EIzjkTngYpLWMZIXsTjy9mKB7EC7qGRcsLwcDn90P@WaMYhvjIfrYZ@QDSKRzvZFxYOfw4mgwk/sbVHx0r7cpS3P7wkcW/y3QQBOojl6clpsvFV4vM4FmTpHi1CEFadzTIeqOhDxLMKb5fhh5Ho7pxC4YYilf1SlmZPH19c4taqEg9xhc@TfNrofix5F9Pdm@dCrMaBTUXY3oc1Ibcg4xKLZjMWhshdVpaYY9@SCehG43T2klalvkCgBjFJ0nkWdbdJv4hL2DM@hC8OOH0OXwTYMb06Zyg/bzimJe47YOTTNwYhrUW4gJIOUEJU5CQXaIRCSb4Zgl/dBGk2l6bZvJVmcybNoAbMJhkKJDVnkhSlgMWzqgh6ZttbIp3RC/vO8FkltuGxHWOIoxVXUStatJIsehEtgkCOmtHifgyEcrQVLT4mgxstnpDhPFr8DAzTuhW9jhb9aoEBhmAlw0N0FyIc7c1ocS8Wv5E849x0/XTVaDEoUwizw61EESAF5hu0Rpxisx2RTW9oQsNGSmWSIce4Sew@0ThMkn5p@Of3CdC55OiJY5wbFJglmDbTaIRaDJ4ONBv@ubcLanJRtOb7Rwe0RCkIgskkoI8XjkPgQQ2PRGeFEUcMfWlGA76AIMrN4mKMWKgluyc6InXgUCrk2fSJeirpA60Y@VchcG2aCF0iIeL75TULghfg/fDEyMvwvIWOnxxhhHOy8QVoIVFfR1dkCst6FhdR@uESorHu2UB4a6IfhJcSgQ3JdNDhaHIOExs4g1kmIV9c7G6F49CgHK@UyL1z0UgqiJq5xJucRc5QMIQrf3xVdkLxELUZEYSe1XSN17KgXSBZjF5TWRfSVHnlAxRCMgdquNk8pws6HgsjhePiJkltxbJmyI/LkyTJNSsmIbKKh6yMDI@nHnRe9/HolQ/rvvoxxzjWEkMAoZhBKly@Oh@gvztcf/cVap8IcwksUqwXN6W31euVrewc5r1psrcLED2T7HF8oXIUpDAlOfQOQpr5Kl67peLjkg@u5PNEA@hz2r5PtqBPcAfd5vsWHBZqCcOLWcdzHRzP9eWEuq2R9C5UX2lRMSUBh2c8wHSatdW48owvKmL0ofFto/fBBTycLeBw4SE8ysBwjuS8lg9HNq1ymdZtENvcBUWqVmRckNN0aVDMU0cQ9zR1G0zbgsNR/fjx0bMn34BGd3NzMy7a6MkUP6y1ONYatOMcMq2GDtqDBd0WPYln7uNkNw7H0w2la2e2fEuWcGENyoABqfjsJ@p4XMiykDyfq7sQj4cNUVTAOp9WA2NGKqGqY2CTbQm6ekAQ04ttGAKIr94CvZPUW4vT6fL1Ot5KWa9T81Wv4@Klel20Ylg0/ox4/OeRtdTIHdKFl/xqhEtJor3h7PERe/np7ik7/XSfHbzY@4x94@gFe7n77BS3MT9/8ejJ4R6D3/6zk302HVHAB6@RwQ4l0PWx2TTx/i48oSrLCPKeM5hwuRPbi3P3E6PPPnWaJk5TbbtG/2GXW1Tb9Co81j50Ryc4hmnRVUF9y8P1FnTPDXRjUblp0WY6XLzPIGwD@rR97PP2nZbVtiCshH3fgWW6/p4u1rOgBEHe@vs@k1xJwittaOkQXT6FK7AuIboB4XHuBsAYfP0VXfxpuTyC2VKZIFzwfDAFT/ePn56w3WeP2d7Rs8eHp4dHz07YwdExWJ9/4/DZJ0DPw5PT48NHL9CLAj49enx4cLi3Sw4cgbTKcKv6lyPXW4mCisGJKs1znPmm@10D2@yoN2rw7NKgbYUui45slD6W0bPemq1oSRq5qL7gVkaaKmCx9d3jTz6HNp@Zb3CG058KpvUH8guXrlZaT7NtSg0qSwXqW0lUV2j2FC1O8xH9CcOT1s0SbTqPkTnJfOC0iKdlmUzewzUqOPbN96ZTXfZBQ0JrABtB@QtWyoxuSIhGk9sEsgKpNXsOHj/HU@OLCIUFoz70l5qUJKKYWCuDQHHzwaGN40FaKXAAvgcHXSTrDXkAlgkceACW5Q6oih7i2hGWEyFG3tEIxTPLc4cv@4MDmhZmm4HDI4N6sQWBEy83KlKDBTfM4E79Ht2DwUd56H4uw21aFkVxKTzeEdHr8Yph8tuJQCbyqURa2wYhZRA2bZxqEMve@MV86AvcgOuEjLbnslg5rrJTXBxk2ha/gaTTM2y@BGq6dId4jxXwPJWyWGBrBTd3tPgF7cSAeGvQLB5BvMdCKzTvGw9iPrqVoiHWSNLtWf4StLsQeHQLgV8EDABSZno6TWqpaPcognHagpVjrgMcieO278LhgZ1bo6Y5E0Gs2op9ab19GxdETs70k/x1ioQdFNFbcwhqJU1ltp0h1HESq3TXAUrBZtcZeBYvw9hsDmjGiZo5CI0NG6T2ulyZSQ3pMJ@i7dihRBvAxUtSbQBT3idV4ng@dx6Ir@nFd8D50AjzdXeIjtHA@02nc2dJnES6NHH4BRRhmivHwc@JR5hw/VOayo53DO/OKpQrjx@dKe9eJ/ECLS4W@J11/qJD/AFjYlpQPWiejxYsDlHvEjXNv/jEHTUwtliDJ6Ql1nIfGPQDuxb06x7WS4EfX2582x33vMy7k@P1dZnHUlAyiWsM3W5sKt2SrOonmaQ4NSaWgIRkJyALsj7muyQJZiCvH@LuFiyFElDERjmC/fa5a0WECPFz1xi1QbKI291EcQfw46xCKyqml13irpZweaRexR6VE5V4arqghIXIGfNFdNKHrMXjoWUp1F7dAvd4NTiQ3/cHV1iJHW8ePgja45XQPgg3JbEcFm@WQrDuD/bdCrC8cfuFwELek8sB80byNrSA0wPmTK5HgtW0q1N8favsqO4BGGx7cQQlABpKbWTTFLV/FmyMR4iHwUwVopPTx/vHx0zm/ROIC3IPuwwtIQYR9hp7Pl1ta9kk7NRAaQo6y4Hy5LvMrGjzn1WVeSHxlogKoYMkBT0CYTG91rVtjbnUEy0LqRC0@p4Eok@5WeyufBnkVgXgG@gDArLTQgtlUFqYzQhvfCw3vAhc0C3JdePwGn5aYc3bbrwzbTgJAwqvCTI6uLNkcfm95Ppx0U@HK1jmmxFluAWaNLQ30E84wfvMIaCqzpbgimLxixQX2XMFO@LTDhd@pWc17L8/QxEjcSWc68IhsS6UY4Ea14/XfTWHFiRiM2DgSk/hyVc0g4cv4sllO1yg8WmjF5ttgkDJxFu0Hoa5AqLXbkrBlc6xaTtZDhTycF1bJ2yqPpY1HJ0VsEvLA32Ma6Hz8@JhPimQtiuTUv5hkuKtxExKPs0XZsb3BMj5XC5zF@z5XPjRlb8vbN6GzMtPrz@A/v0UpDtxaXgfOPfwWdL3nzLACtLxpfV@hZmLCKrOgjZlJu/UGIXxA1z4uBAggwcz48Vk86nG2XgOt8XQeYsUhk5BbuUhVIWDjPJac4v6N6uTQ4F8Z3prH54er2wYCJcO3uCq/KfO0DWnu/JCx6aEnHDb6qybORzaFIzvZ@ojlBhtY1q52Y522/EFrzxX6EnzbeGctMXuJL7sNumPNVAiNLyo4l2EOLpXmh/eU7RSOKsHh0/22QadbdeeGYuUh3I8JHvWLHsVAiSDaVwCmw/aw/exW4Qf4JD0QQKZaDdfjGgTvxM3oghozVW62EIsCxWyVZsv/bbbNGw8wyMpf@wyOfkAItIo7P7RQXzRyHq6NBMfkHMHdgxiJWVFlSkquOGALkKaBcFLE91DDRbu1PBXSq64QdpIaYV0fkui3NlJL9mvbtWSG82yzKDxNey@Oxpets47TveizXps8GVj3Jy8fcNYLssykJb@gJ9NquXLuHM8xjbhXWBbaeJcgeAO3et1JjOm0lmiOLHMpv3w0hqLk4E6zUXcITHHpWyj73MhbrHzyv1qvla2y@lSv2rXSrjJz0uUvYSWiKHDA2hFQcbwmfmqV8M2NTzqatoXdAM93UYltoYw2hoCLk@NoeU82X32ycxoHCoAOAQm1nrTgDq/h/AjXM2Ge09U27yMiWGyJEOOlVBBkj6iXUEablin8WQcjmlZgBmUShK0WXdM70lc@iitjgaeQz4iIQVZi11b19JH/jamNI0oQJCqVfPR2SY40zAxnBjirhO@ilrRuLqm4d7JeAhEFWOSOJTPZBn3FCKiYi9XtSa5qmk0u4gEXrx5zW@1396maziB1VyVRvFwKYcxpA0T6RoacQIEPgOabcAkSHN3aduHBNlHu4YG7kJjVB7tk6EF8hJpiuiDy7/ZFe1vovjbQABO@I@4zqWKIU6heYEiyfcO0uACHjE22/HHaQbcVskL5SPMLMLm6ZWnwGmlONEIkxVkAvePLpGcnFbwiBwoGtluZSMIH@fBiSQ0Ty1sLtKSipS8KvjpTaPFQtEUP5ofOESKj@6kBo50QffoqQnVasL2zF4PkOa0@GhKDjTS/l6RfiJI361imrUAee6v3PJXZvxV7s@RmoZSoYGfBiqGA8mRq2m4GyZPgyVvpVVmpLyoUNJNFVSSadjSqrCu6jl1axq4EhQl58rAY3vGQwn5vFpQ@txnbSZOwOCBf5X7C/7WRckHWM6EfTibPn4lUUAmLZ4Va03muFS1rd4Ob7QCH2QzGajJGI@O5U1sxyul2IMpxAlocDjOT9W2Up5CSWi@xKE6I1e2H8qqUDJ2YvNo8F2MtyrWgjoSohKlmSDCjWnDIqRD3mshEAQTGY35NbfiR56IyJMQWAy15ifLd0HequCQtfkqXsZ9kdf48iv7LHJ@uMhiz4845mOeeb67eZZAJHTX5MVkmpUmuF2EO4pMrWhFpmlP/t/irm6rjSRJX7ueIi1ho8KSSsIGYwS4BQhbvfx4kDDmAFYXUkloW0hqlQCpbfbM7sW@wO79PsK@yrzDXO1TzMYX@VNZhbDp43OmuUBVlZmRkZGRvxH5ZZLi7E5i39oFNnkG8gx2G9vgT00/YXcUuqe4J3cToiQdRShq9X2oChF45/zDW3De@TTHHvaCiShjmeHzKSwndsAdULIhsJoYSSa8Hg57sDryhO@Wj1AriJDFJZhbIorWyJ53qvDskfGzeFIH0ilRXhyA8i0cRKKA8LqDW8dh2AFEE3Wt2HHpjvNOuT@VGxrUZl4uymPmgbgOpdWUVvsdmwlZc7L1QNLh0G8GeYfmaCHNfhxZ1LZs32o/HedGABdGQ9qq4/zlutv8desd7Lmvi4WXRUtkN8ocXMi/fBUdsCIh6YDFAk1jl4qvHMeyDTelbTgHglmxi4H@I@lmcBP0@4FTphGDI4Y0aQ2D0U3QyjvOYWCMwKALVYZlEuewB9ejptzcoUmXT8qIU8JhVprDSMPwi/FZmoubbCvLOjBaRdZmquqbbgsC1CdO2gNYh9lgAZgAKQ8kugrGJJQFV8RZYtuz4oXnLlfYiCJpAOfEsk0YMfQH426TaoZ3spwekZJmkCizfivBCeXX7Pk4HJyfxQCOx0QS0AxoU9K3eHCU0fwP8SBUwbSN3dc141HvN@C2Qs09GHWp940EzLXCySzeqYLr76s1UTvYqR@XDyuCnj8cHnysble2xeYJ27hhKGesWvH@YJd6F2NNl1bzA/qQKtcoZYoDnPL@iah8@nBYqdXEwaGo7n3YrRI1In9Y3q9XK7WsqO5v7R5ts/WdKIj9g7rYre5V6xStfpDlXHUyJ0onDnbEXuVw6z29ljeru9X6Cee4U63vIzNY9cviQ/mwXt062i0fig9Hhx8OahWBgjnb1drWbrm6V9nOU/6Up6h8rOzXRe19eXc3UdCD4/3KoWAnAauUmxXisrxJS1jkxOXcrh5WtuooUPS0RcIjBnezovahslXFQ@VThYpTPjzJKqK1yl@OKBIFiu3yXvkdFc7JfEcqVC9bR4eVPTBNkqgdbdbq1fpRvSLeHRxss6xrlcOP1a1KrSSc3YMaC@yoVskKXN/FWRMNkhaF0/PmUa3Kcqvu12nMOPoAfweXKvmYBENclinpNgsYbhAoLQnp4PAEVCEHroCsOH5foe@HkClLqwwpwKNiq25HowxJiHW7mGK/8m63@q6yv1VB8AHIHFdrFZcqrFpDhCocMk5IdSjTIy416on4ko@krI7W3CxXp6juiPL2xyo4V7FJA2pVpS0stq33SuZ5wN9amyjdAfYM/Ct7Y6V9/9NNADTJ@zsys/doDGLS1sF2hUZkBVaVigKOaNRZSUAp2WE00phAeo1B1rSCi@tOo9tvD3DG1CSTGx9XYSeLi0hc3O9w5nzj9g@1v8IJ0ulG42O5QQvdWqPhZh@TMsbG91KobfBvxXJVGQFzj5U3Nn5WV6Xc12KC2niuDJ3sqAcDBGJK6T@Xrm/@VeAKz2sFKhkO74Ow3joKpdnkEqYU6hr5sCNupIiy5J0Jfu8qdeCEGU0@32xgnxSekRxpENK//tfoRQ4O1gfqneV2l@dhEctsdH8PdDYyE4ZE4H8KkaDb5izzYRD82skU7Oyw5s93BoNWxnV1Go47pnVgJ@N@J/lF0EkkzyXTM7NsdlbI@KFed/MUxtiflciEqpf8iEuWwb/GmH9czY3EfMCuKWfFm9Vq0zLzXCaHR1JWKGgLHK/gSsacb6/8qXqM1Vxh8VUp8f29@S7bFvwFgTpLA94ppzvnn/fnMgI1MMbiIJF0FUKG51lptL@JiXxLES8Ria8O4LH6MuBxnURCE9lrv2fnidF41J3Y3FM//O6wvLd5tLNDXSe4fbWy9Hq55BjYrU9Z@XuCfBi2lVHHhjSO0zyNg6xWskUTH24pFnh2pP6swJ6HiMBN15XGH4HzYPw24p5M6MhQ3BDXs/ThopcKIIeUYACOp47W15ktUylAJlZUF6W58ic8xfdprsQ6oJxZelOutQn@gbZp/rqJmwIpBVIqxmC5pLm0uuB@L7WjXUV5ccPAPYiST2k9ljBuRga81cX@szhdy29Kt61aDKUrI9orVzunJCaeJrkQ2q@iL1v2B8YZURvAjB5GXz4pfaPHEwVwx3B3fjguj2skxh2TEvvU0Wa0KvSpony@sU5V9Py5yWlNYJffVUxx21PbyQYYxGoNzMo5nArXRYJwyeCIJLNkD9if5l3xRWoqwDtAp6Q0Vr2T5s4qjqJS0vgh6l2jUghJy4CcSKndmjwcHeXE4FhoccbE9EPyYPp/okxm0F@jFSdRj6RlgQA@SpJMVcqKlq8slO6tNjRY1o1Imvank4jMnV0xl6ZgynozkedrSASqdqb6wwnDHrYzMwQAJcfGht1@jUvapU9Lp59SrkoOO0m/eTXMCDVW6KHiHt3c8nmWp11ZbVvBiytcuddkZbhLScVPcuF2wa2elkyJpbx4FqYkOVfjf3gLvAFiGjxr6aX0Wk1qVkG1Mt0PKKgla8BpGcQkmpbePWi1WxAWRGas71eWLy0oIr0Bfu6Xky/0GAjpnhtHXJQXYNUZBQ/43lgmY/BRkHUX7IjZC0DnWYs3Q3Dnx/gWA0RPUmeovoiayDxjRxFkEnkdRjiD6G7dPImWh9Vbwz3vTEJDDfdHfYk8H8hdLR0jLwE@FIf2cfm82POnxHLvccWWKuYt1AZZ@C4iM7ktodLjfpPmYDCiqaOPchOP2e7UzYtjtekQ9MPrkcIvpPGsO1I7EnrST9lg2iRX7zzMSEB2Zi3sjnFaoZVn/eAiXQXwEJXwJJPcssiQ8mod3dCbjt3Ji6LIrEUhayQThiVlIa6JZfH1q4wlBaogQwOWYDc0iwv22eR8YHcwze92MPoVYz@mQP1W0DLIpBZJ3guUlVTtM8ZjcyyLPhyEvKNBVYEdECOJotxIM46qNEa/Vuqk/JpSETomsEu5JH88H6Ok2luKMooUV@VOyreco8qElBYVNKgBCy0uLjErsxZcdw8uxhgtNG62FqmzvulSVuUkYv2ZnjriSfab5ukET2qTf/1ZiNZDX2DjVlNQMIw5K@yq9/s55g8@BcfdYNSy90RpJtPyh9h@46XPoM@6qLcOFexf0x@HwZRWAE2vO/GYRiPz8@Cy39ga9PxOd9D1aZ0GWPaJ7PHwOOVHVFhnNLgN@eoeDmhZkVrT6Fniy0gYNrwbu2TJguYKx8EwY7spjEfT8qWEieCdczgBCjNesX4PkxhpJs2rpSiREz9/yv54Rbf0YNqXxVmJpUUfBFQHt5HwoJBnSMd8MMk6fFq6F@HiWxEsHi9ETvjuAx57MY7fkIjYDBPjWDNzzy3BLgRWZg9yfNqaZFuMQTgC0FKwHeCOmTDDn7M@7pylXuQtPAVWRXGlYCWVVpQJcAjxMH1Y3Iuv/2TuiYEfYL/4cpa2zFIE7uLaGm0plOsVhTJKvLB7YJf7aO6JqRfrdmgU6sWINiZJqvHg6UPSYM8fmhQpmL17WokWmaGFD26DyzSoy2lMXQwq82LeZdwOTEHK40zhYYUNvuc/y40fRly5c4aOaUtRzlhMPySqJkkJV3Mm3GttliWm8vdbzOLiY2stIcD1WS5n1gWumZSeufAJlK4cX2HWGoyoM04lpKdcPebD8WA4/0jpPdh3zERmmyXrput@1xFYKts6DZYLLRbt@hSP05KT5CehNHGJsacZ6RCWr/xs1DwpxMl6A@1tvTH9jhweklnkN2UGFVPfLdn2MSjewKNXDzSmSTHvACktme@nDSp44@EeRNGUy6sG9xgNdBmNqXy0SCXEZKT0eAmx9ineE/JokeSQb4tkZ9fPg0JNOslpyFMdFAO5hDwB3I5Dm9QvDdtwvgBMnJzhmk7KTDgn2Smb8oq5C4AMI0ASxKw4yEX7UHIHN6qshB7x7QDtTAPeQkX0RPS0YXs4GNB/IzBG5VebO8rjoTHNFc9LktLEUKJVBcf6FiV93pxeTxsTpnJPFNTEZ4jClOhe33T5@FL9aFkoHlGQqTlYefoWsiiMK14QN/TPDmpMMAeOslIpYy0q3hAa3DVQW6BVSqcXyOUqZn/dkdR4eDeoZkQLCPk5g58XKgXgvJcLRtpIMmlNEcVV4patzRW5DZkkUij5DvGrpiinurxwJQKB5JjSrxeJAmBNmXsYBRh6x9a8GKOqjijhehHNkj4yKmrk5zkjHEJVEV4tWTEKs2K8sWnkZhKhicXsOBEjNGeZHSWiQgPdTF6sGK9nlyeKQRNirftS4lQVqlbiMjQ1JwVIj8yt6VFOiyJbUBrMga@W3Fig0W8OfVOwQgvJUJKP4fA0V0yGrhRiobFsFxfjSWMpSR6unWsskETh2gybXuHH/vhoig15bnxCrUVGbJah/LP7WErdYt2W/9dQrPGhbD3H0PTsk@F6@dWQV6zEQNm/DcAuFO5/6ccLqx1TNSPqqgCGpdNnXTJyPcgT1hRGepQKC10NtGfwCfSSdtAWH@s7OzHU14up9jO6CkZLhUIBOnxhY99r12rsJHUHXjy2177u9bzh7c@jjxced/24wr4XDlb1AjqgGqE2EeYHo468GAI8UFTEzqlzrFjqX7fb9g0MMFCi7qjWZEwFhiB4/Okan5ePdd7/YZJqfP0FBUT5fhGm8d36cp6pqGgrFKWGR/BNShvPSDz40IZ7tjFUMTH0y9qZiYYtd33jCwYQXGzClcXoxe6XyDs59T7o9QZZcYy7fwEU8OQumWBnx05QkFFgYOTDvdchw9FmRXDT7VnHihHFVnWQ0@OSvmZCw8IDGv8w6FQmw0zq9HOKRhUq8gsU8wXgqbMi1Um5Civ@EWSlHhLbj4p95Q8zTZZTMjKN9KoBR0/E0ctidubSJxbF5S0xJbPvx4ZQZ7ObZ6wGKrrLUwENZc/VyyV5ILoRbupsUmxDhgVJQ/EEyJXHpcBJsz@vV7wZt9uP6xT5FgBZsf/0DpFNANwCVfMjeQJE@19y1Kx3Engicn6Duzru9ztI0EACx3nWXP/tNlMul8Xc8MULUS5v0kMuJ8qbZbGND5ubYpveN/H@fH1xaakk@9xt9wt93NQf78Qm0eANzhfNy9E2vVLYOo6NwVkbVTznrc9lS3ON9bWNUuidljdxqp@e/v7v//n3//gvr6xe/gcvm/xy@tlEyufz3lzzy9zzuxLeT7fP5@cuTueG5/OdErTsHwwaPqiOc37kPZofXThpOQpYX9mNVC@zGXxGJRX6Or8rf/Qr9S6rIt0MvbT6GsqLo7iPTTcD63uAY5QXtILXdw4kV/LERJqITrEbT7XTDOB/R@MNSZJ4gRuoTC9NK3rfHmgwJoIxqqQVEA9PWW8CHGmJgBRwFJdGrFy3HwZ9bIDf8JRXFs9xfPrtjhtKf73Pe2FnczARC2cZsVAQC1mxkErxT3H5DX1157wuDufKaLQaSKWyFBJZFuBlKMIuz/N4@cBX7STE7ThzfGMPKGmUCo4sD8FlzeKPz8rI@9bCjvME92UKuUPCNiYkSX@Z699RtXyhGHep2Ekbnig01CKGM7MMKqZ@MQPyQ@kHEOV8JQWyOqAsYejjA8l48vQXVdcOXybEhCHWw3c73O7xgcaiub5yeY4tpXDLEXvPy68YG0vyLDSzjRCZf8QA21PkarLABwnn0/OOdPK2SsnFlIew7fIp5ZOuDtNgrF3TZaJ/E5YSSGduW3BzfXWsRflxS@uKSHWNdcXKKpV0/RaOleTqujfuDtVpBc4dDeqLye1OtiTUKBOSdCRk/@r9Fsb7BBooKlEt8q6sqWgNUHTZEvrqZDpVsJuXhiNLCN7nDLXtr4m27Xp8SESrg9QBZsp48rX9bi9UoCsjFnbHH13gckC/zfepjaXZjLfzcMdpguNB2zCdZ8rscR61ZypKejjyO1d@VqT3B/WRP63SsEUzn3Ez71IJgcAEJtD4VNaziqcZliVSVcISMUVhxyHcXdCbqtvRZN2mzJETVKluCgp1BY0gpk4syeBrrK4Scoy0@g9Ugs3yvc7bGCNVF8s9LxyNFKWUfWqGm9m9puPoHOy2YxpOypGsmpapdUElusZAe8V2X@rJe4AIUHmn1CFAdRJh@Q3yx@jUCfp@bHAa9hx9zt8rCTkuoj3zTZTSGcnRV54WowvvwBXNIz/HQSDk2KTRjJwnmcyTs1Dd5pa2xxHG@Dau@J4vuub@Ob6/jA@GiKN@V3aWiREqugIjL6rs@E8U2j2/Q/xNb/0pVPEsnXn71HNPP5/1zxcyZ/2vZ7@7zInqkvUomxNpZcvWPZZqKzQyetnYq3ZKCzXS4Fk/HuGsL@QRFksExIiXOf3snX/1iKGzNO6QP0tLgcSqDJx4387PA3nvHpvpOBde2nniLri68jNvi66gsZV/UYfygyt/iQu9qORdelrnjNpEio/p/nYtT5yE3spi4dVi8RWthDrBJDcKrjHe5sLri2BCU4kQy1kaes5@j2lDTBB3k9Av0ccJlVPeaiKPnoTqjJLqQlUz53wco1aUJi91guKTlBktFSdcXBPHh@0RLoJZQSqn4zIUlPQctLQvg/EzHFwhHz9Ev5Y8HCI1Ek4G0kWEd1BzoKzvXnlIQ13dXOb5mFNebAG6lYlQ9Xppa7ToD/o5NVlz8/MlTKJxaKa3UlgpJNvovSYaa6FzajI1/1QUN96@/tt/H/yWHqc3Fr3jEf2O07@ll1fS8pEe6O2lfrtJb6TXEG35Lj31aA1Mj6//9r@UfuNnooOQ6Rr921jStJan6Y3cOif5mt5Ypofi4iLl@39//SuVYU6u2HAV61wjK5ixkpbIlt9n3aVwUUUp5bJ0PupW@FwWaEgHQ1qb0wv8oiaLKwXepUsrp4qbQAFfaXcUNcSzX9aYPYXkToZ2p6CZkUywjgxykqT2oGgLy3VDe21AeSM2xS/P8sshrQB@Ud4cJkvjufEshMfQnFwWUQVmZI60npcPG4W3KePdsZrSLiUlPYXE0k71tSsvS/8P)

efunge takes the same path as cfunge. They are split using [`2y`](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#system-information-retrieval) (efunge uses Erlang's arbitrary precision integers, cell size is `-1`):

```
:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#
```

`:` is for Chip.

**Test driver updates:**

- First argument: language number to start with
- Second argument: list of languages to test

Answer (score 2):

## 290. [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 13550 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                         @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=  ($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_ )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  
♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 (   *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
#ceppp  
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
T:251  
E:0  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa





















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu91&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在5"" 16 ""6int 21*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]putsR 8ogrFloatecho 2
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if 0
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>;
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if 0
#endif//*
/*/
#if 0
p;
select 192;
.exit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{
endif #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#<<<#/<+>/\
"""#";   print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQdBgACbzSbv5dzuZg/Jvn1nQDS6ABSAugSq0KgCCTTJjplZe6yR5LU8O6sYSbu6o1lrLVkbsfKG1xp5pd0I6euGYj/pB7QeDofCofkH43NOZhUKIACyR5oIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4YbvdnP4vgw547vUmn53jMM12PtYbWhTlU2aMJe2hYbk7PSBKG2h12Rn3T9tyiFGEaY65nDD3WM@zOyOiYLAKuOpva21bPM4dJ5poma5g95xL8M4zZ5iU7tJtWCyAxzzk3beutOQS/LGOPzd51/9pjTaffN@yWywZDy/bIN8fYcwMs7VHznBkN1xsaTc9ybPDKM/bC7hn9RstgFHwwNHmkTQagmucUZ9anwNhTZ@iakILTNF3XQcctcDSGlvNk99knc@G1NPvEAKQGPXM8l7ymsZeWOWzNx9DZ56cHB/OuGfaZ4tjs4DZKWpbtjjzn0JuHn2O7HdM2mK5uqfq8Zx6I6Zm9QrqQnvECvwNrCKVpiFIrTkvGHvUb5hCIL4rw0vK6KkQ4dTjBmWP3JswcAzDAsQ3BTI9ZWFosl05jSPg/MZuO3ZqCBycT4ABcsz/wJkxhtiN4ALycIXMHRtNUWmbP6lue2WI9C7Bz2gIbl0GBs3NzcukMoeAVzoqEiDswm1bbwigiB66EzPbYbIw6zBl5gxGg57KW5RqNHgRrTFjLbBujnpdkDfAD4pH7Zde0BUqW3cF8vJy6IAQbqgDHfl0D2li9HgN0zhEdTNpl2@hxie4YtGESlmYLQe1PyQWQjJ7r53424ZlkMN7zodMZGn1g1JZJNPj88Dlzm84QbPDDsLwWrALTNDy2vc2i@88eR1klIKM6bEgBScvsijEW8T3ZhdEbmS7rGxNI2/agcjGHys@PIUFwFl2LFlk0k2F6mmWzLAuVrcD0XJpBldgCA9RaPaPBL8/0AstqwPe5aBLTaQ@NjtUzOZSO02sjoE3kWD3HdHins9Ek921SGpssU2D5TbaZY5vw3mJbOiSCELNM28rBLw8/gLAFGGjwy2R5SgFbIDtBFtgeaxt9qzfh0AcDBN9kOY1tAkRAUwPIeqGAsWefMCyvC0TtGhcATulZ5ygqzEBaYEml4JPa2EiRuEK5yJNzu2avhykCkYA8uQLbhBTzkOEspAo01Au6n/FOl7JOOG2m4Qf4bUJuC0DaNFApjWTahB/YQQTpIGt0ECw6yApdA3cdzBmECuHy4JeHcsoHZNVbRFeQrBBXQ0KiMNEw/xCNQbFlsgwKLgtFm8GizWUY4AkIbOYZyJOCxgpZVthkhQLbSjMguwbIYLlrIMc0QEJDYFCcGpSnBohowCgaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFMtDz@IB4UugZJapCmrm9N2Qpw03OQyVyG@E3PQ9Fvgh8QSwdcdeAUHbDVC@CPcQtAuAKy46ZPCKM36BpICygBZGJgMyBIDnAi2BAezPpmhrMThW6YntWUbiSoUbz1C0sbX3Jg7QdJwgyGjScw35R7YoH0i4MwmhVUI9fsAReB/GgaYEaWhZqOUsOHY3kqylhookznAhtRqvozybgkHhpDbEFBVrXM4ZBhWGho3SQJEnfUcM03I2xnp3i1QTKZIFTbhtULEKBqY3jUBsA36kJ6k1m020OnT3Wrj4Ki5ziDJSIXxNIlAvrUuTSnqE@lljEY9ECWg7sJhBgZPUDm0iBdgFSFcKocIYiE8ZpdCwBSUiBTraHZJNqLrEPsDEjfWRSLTK88yCCUR6EmIcMGDghUF@PYo16vCE2d2WSZSqplXqTQhTcbs80F4uA3JNAWChANA9pxakgRiwDSA12lJurUL1nX6c9mjYuXwyDrXQvFf@/SmEDptUGymGOjD9oGwybdhka7DxzDSxBLwuWNziFrOXbUC6BcDqFphUwHOQGQPaKJZ/VN0MUciIIlniWkUbgRZo0JsDJRK6uSKsYxmSOUKs0TijtkQw68skCj1ho1kWqYtmUTB0Fj4FJLVQG4XOFU0QBVbmgaLR4MNQvEKKQbQUtnAtGFGtAkQKidmLYLmo6rMgtVQmD4jtMGHqPmGdQMiDpNp0l5x5wHTmO1qUpEaeSb/nmPWaw5GDBwB90E0DpIF6B9db602Fvw7HVd1muOhsMJGw@gAKw@hPKaTrsNTPvWHHQBBOu3WHPShFppeFLLIeHTHMzlNrCtmxDGNiHHe8@/wTomEBoa4jYgSUw@xX0wIOyJCobNG2nbACIh9s3BhCgCYIIYbcdR0b3lmC6xBygxQWXHxFyzQ5UBalZ7Kn76qHQAX4IiYAO3gqwRFQrhY4LSwsxgUqLcPzFtqCxN4EOo5lByqIbusjao/KE2GnU6o9k0B57gDIcEmGWH9JijA9RjyFURwFS3K60/BBVsBgMJgko@04Qab@Oc5Crq96ReGShdRb8CmnPbDDRXxmVJb3IreQhxMZe6/BrDzGDwWl6Cw4AqASp1JBZGHgoPlIdWs4vSz0P5QgoG1K/h6Hb2wS2c/LDPlHaQNmKjgaCR1FTghHgsh6HAr3cbkDroIazKjAMGnXG4A7Th9hdAdgIke62wq5oyVBCDdwHtO7azACoQM4CLQWZ9qCyIGU9QYBi9gBmpurgzZYQietrlxaYLWs3BwBlCzeDyZoJCjBdZiLsc3j2JBa1DHLrLs40pNBJRbOI9j3e1Bj3o/lAVw5oKqqQBQgLkF1f8Qdw5PMUQwlTrCZbA75KEPWcmaD1t20Rt1BhOOBDIHjTIkNCEWcMhSMALbBZ4q@M3HyrxKbQCRquFQhXJQfV@PnEVOXpv1LDG872LJjqqX7rShTFkbexYDEHNgEoUi7bdaLxE7hQz5CWnnIGXoqj8LUNACqRCkcfa0FeBNuAABM3JxG7G5JkqJieZPPLaBTkOBozItTL2NWPgzWP3Jbgh0/TPoV6TrcQ60GArCrwVdCNM0COloocxBM0CKiEo2FtbrYbBrkF6DJky3qPYqBHSV1OzQVqm3QrSEoRAXML5VXkS7rBJBiXUoGEOMDjlnBqJGQLekxIUUQaHVEo0nehA@h33I02GO45sGhVgMa58xNlVoJ1DAxAjZCxQN6ym5dWFgvLgga@qrJXLwGygP4HYbMXDer0/fKKCpIbAKukfIhHVc048rBuxOOQXA99wbEBRAk4tV9iV1x1CjSP7jQSBgKySjZzsE1aU8zPrfNSaL2gbHTGQjLUO1CSr6cklCdp9XhvKq6ganaEq6P1RpCoyL8Yn0LeYl1yxQGURbGi6qPCWBSqhEo4hBoJXF5KIRxVuU4bemzR7QiXgJqjsXBo1AP1z0UEPBFFS6AR@pb1VUzkQrA4cDnu@e/ppWdRF7plqWHZxxqHnNI0eOa9jcNmP@@Tw0fHu8TfqC2D0rEZx3iFlZQt5bGpHY6Vjj1JZVS@uh2FMAT@ur4aNEWfDyJLwZoozDqlKkyY0LmOfnEfHn82TBDQhJAelAGb8zak0PAwoXVLDcLtzjTDrJBKQZBDFD8uUQ@bDDAyIOvobPj7PR2/fYuHNIzUQ7ohZb2RwAL5j6tD246noOaeA@V6NNm8RKS4ooJaNw55TUzikj88nqDDPI0NadIhlPjk62D8uE9iu4Z6bvZ5CQVKuB7qUMWypwPO9UcuUFoUB8QemJkuoU8RRlSZcFxK42Zwh8LRs2RL4AAB7N6rDlF7fz5rbBdz35vNGrkoz4ACyE4R5vTKsDzU/FNEQHtjENbGTu6gVJY9pYxU4LWyxAt/ZZquZy5mb2a1ws9WcptkKA@2TUmw5vt44BK9zV0EXdapFCrVaoH/y5BbiLimR0BVQfMzcHlMpLbcnYe9FsVjUTe1B58zpmepLkngyk@OpVNQf71SbLnU3Q@H3x5YXS8f5V4tDWEh9d/dQf@wHFmN0NHZBnQbsfWPLNGzj/ELTBR6xnZ7TcdgGxOHaoZ8gqE1Ls7nbcexbJWSgI2Y1ghMWIH9xqMYYQFtjvaU@I8UK91T5ZIdhu5cgpbV8BolEFCJQKQqvfmlcGECuab5PDr@5D42IlkunA3OaHiBBKA6RC03NkCs5MAUSUgU@CzMYTF7cqu2@hxKaPcBMC0EXRNydei90JImpphaGX4ASn1EKhUGFGtVxy4m6NASHMgvHPtwBNNo0dNTEEnCx2@8B5/NBGj6@4IE@jQUA3aoojooZLh97gEhiHsGPD3pYAIHG2ILxJTuYP4GSoVikekOXHFRvHATpTgcPUKEHjoMECSfsWIB0sGkssAMCFyLzjOzyjPCUyGU2S@fQ5bARWsNkBaVheXzozhkNcXzeaoXzBsEzOg8D0ChzoTKjgXzo4/PBEx6ZcgEKngHqPyj50E0AyUnDUSZlweCTAKjnuTj@BF2XtILjoQBfYQ/3uobdNHlfUOmjgsSUwT6LesPUrvLNlKG8BQZdITcx87vhOSkq9FOfADTKEExKUQ9IjG6Q5HH6FOgl9aXQ85HflEmDideFHCtNJhtlZ2Da8/oc1/Zi8RJNnUSj6peOZceuomtra9FitBJNgmkHTNto2kFTAkw7ZFLIhOFUNFGMJJnQt0ox0K0Wvan6kMfxGvLAGKXCW2sQM6rFYqaWNKqa@Or4jUNRAOUhtIIfgBONl8tojMflyiWOwELbHMr7HvLOSXNoDQQJvgaVndsFDTJEBFDdsaUemiXUO1dTpF8egkJoYvMRG0bPqumz2tnVWStxdhNNYux4ySiD7heD9GJ9tTN0RgMQytVsUdFq8Xg1U6yVGuVoOroRixWUHiRkxOMfF@IJg9M6FoVeZy92dhYFkgrqVJvdIcEbJ/V4PCAU4AE9iha0TbGoelWA9BvxWjwRhbjxaBL6AuVoFOjSRCK4lGnU9jkTHUDn0sXxZeixhocKSZjTUDNW12@ag@5kGA4Q9KihBcXRsen8GlQGmqEMN2xvefywsJ7R4v02jYeDhgs75igLBxMurSWO6VlqZq7XbxUulHbf8YzU5yooREEispuKrkVTipKSGflwSJTtp5aLVdiwTWfkhkcRFg5uYOrgetodgbD0J8KTwFXWQDKbXYdF1x8CdBaM3mKDgAPRCh/O9gG0mir8UIieHh4xHAM1bY9miC2Qizh7zHtcGiHBRY8/7pbLD96oQWolisPSmJDVsZ2hqQBJIIZE87k0@y9VmJgkPqRe7a0xR@G7B0mSUm2ZIBEPeo5BtOXiOjTMO@iH4oPuDVGOzZbUA/nRBvGo8rIYmq3UhkRzLs6wCy0E5AYlsR6UVl94pBx30FK9MUSVYqD0zHhyzQ3UykvW0nU938y1i74fcgUQuwuFhBqnDeqr76Vo4BkXhbzPu3y@/v3s6PE@7xelRu6QelbYR673ndaoBxzMdaJj0@4k2T7wk2U7fQvI4Md/e947dhyPa/BgWdbr4gqx1R/1DOrPzXe5VsZrOg2nR928VVGn4UdD1@gZvIPp@@5@/vTw2fMXpydltRgKlDIu@oIyh@FJAZoH8QdxXc5i8npOxhbIXymCAkN45NFjJNaJALV990109ysHjnQK9wK693GNCOj/Qtcna@AoAm5RQFw3gtPtwvFKS9@g@1JNKQinUbhLXEESwvZK08n9wmu3Z5wz5HyuoJDpTZ2z5MzXj8xocmGUcjwQLiaZCRMGlKcwwZqS@XBCDAVzgF2z54/zH4OKgWPZ0Er3UBGyzUscZ@cLO0y3iZrzyCZZiwPhrNk1hu6tzgXUjoHCQ0uRNeJ4aI1SqINI6ykmBqJKxPOg3PMJBJfLQQcUcOrjbFf4jBIwhjXk0xcpPkS2XgcQ25WSP92/LBimFI0GwQgq4QYxKJs0r3Yrq8EsqUsjXxJFKUluqvrqbKynlbPx5n4t5RIR2kw@Oxt/nNa/kJMMF2SsP0h1zBImt5RaZOejRc0uCACWGM@SDMphZLedXkvhQ9NQ/oAxjT27wVxgsCSERDe4WEN/NYiFs8xi1Q4IvtBCkltw54qucjtAaOlJAAhqwxW7Pk9eXLMqtEUXqjvoWV6N3aieU@9i5r3R0J5fpMKVw@HQmLiSmEous93jTz6vpmscgtQ3cLi5wEtr7K9xAo0WNBhcSgYmnBD3LI@aaJr5szC/mgpIjWlkEtAHGDyBEgsSEjlC1K/N62le2qYHSpSJmLuTfpKZ8Ru13TM8z7Q5b/Ex/@Xk5oOzIpkyJb8jRvqKLE3DoaAyWugHKJbYyenj/eNjFTjUjUX3cdi0CNXOaHZBc1iWaZ@S4cwX2cetKPsY48QZpgJVCroFdREfmLcEzA0dA0gdRUHHHMbAMY4jnk1wpkFmishVJ0EgXNbQ9IhGAbCYGYc8EbDiQvxf2LwPJPAssihLECWB3LEHRaCtFVdHtvVGdaGRIIUSgkR5L5LWr5XXYyS@1rU48c/Q6uOMDXR@SJ@DPFSrbA2kG4WWWfkde1VNK1u1xDqr1Up8Hg4ionZO6@HE2ipD0JMPWpOAFDgfiv5Ve26FnZ8Cja9gLI6fBjwrCb4FZIejxuR2LZXXdTkeIKu8BQfuKc8juWAFGEfRX3tAIoSWKswuOZhd0BDK1gvqLs@t3ITs@AgE@cHJghjPJVsrMy0e9zHjgF4aQ@wEF9lzx3WtRo@WlrV7Fl@qETTWRUEYAcmnTDi5ElYMohvWZ6hnWBjT9YR8lZ6gBPlTQwN9IswZOcTi7AqJSaTUkYrs@hodZLauM2IDGZfzcfre@L1TkI9PHED2iVieGNY5SGiISWQUHWeS7HfDZmdp0Ier@KmLOe1VuZDD8bj2aNnnDo31BqZ6WtVyqDEGsfvnvdsx25bbpddM0AAHHlZfhp3bb7TptSAADXmKyTRyoME0oStDcRqpY/rQuNqClGcnkGeSbZjtkd2hmQc0M@XNHSGVrQIFbjca1rKgQARcDuJ/FwQDWYk1T1ezqubXHhyqgWYR5Cfv3UyzPr/2gM3QHRopD2KJ73/5Vgvof7t0utBe4RhlYKiDpoAlpbSXFpaIihZ6LS5YPoc56lkGEYZMd4FsGkPIktELDItB0wScooC@0cfhRFHiwJv4Al10BZtxzPlsgP9dnMiiAXUb5HZzWdi5tRg8KRr6hY5fi4jAdS7LpEgkZHkhmGM@/BrqgqPAvRspf8EEI2bm5d4deSP@BnX4zkK0BvhbVTdFyHTOaGgmdC2NhmWuKPKhcT5qOcrgvBOoxfkFYae5p/kfBbQSMRVUR@Pi7PMMDq0ONPf@d1mwafuauqTPXVzh2iN3oDSol97iNqoI/RUpDHv8vSyIJbYRBIblVLN69LonJwrowChiJjSFS8yUENGsOTL3jMYEVaHuh3NZMKsIEqfcTCTSmSXTSoPB8vjYP6X4W1uLY4/VJqfHojGEFF/GpvBRNsqwWNh2R6lCc2X1jZ6it0LGpcJ80aTkraDBfAbFMS@g0Oi1ismxQWqOesZwalrB4lM8/GmGZSPWotkQdbnp9CwXK3RvmdT0V8ZM08KFhPQKzX5aiyjZgo4otuNKYFosBZymhyvGlrDVPWQaX6mF6@FCfKI6y4jVdC7xt1SD6EJnmL8XN2pvF2J1D/mk9Jo9A5rypS3CzPghjk/ewauXlmvSazFhzxci6jV7C91na4E/Mhge6buLs12r57jshN6rCNQZAhX4ezFPh2lpGbZC4@Vh8wox5E9xTgvU6HWcXr7QSRnwWlrqo2EbRb/43lfIBUJK0@4QUr4G5Nia@C4V7eep4fldBUQbNIa4vC1kXNHKLpJUYnpmee6gb4Bze4tzdpAuUEw1xccQlySMszKXxsT//hytxzLS@q3HYEIaNSh4GGGrAAZvyLXsnye17OrUWvcTSrfAbt6ViVDhnvdMaK/ofatImZ7WPjCGlk7fX0S1eyNzZC7saxw1vjRxj9@Kfsb9kUqLbKyLwXycP8BF6UGot6JzeC@ssalG20phYkCv3bxbm5kVagNQwAfYe34OhudouB2jY48GM6U600Gzj1eTrDvwq7TTmsEOfT5UDhXuUJZmVHTXpN/KThPv5OH6kHI2nU4LHSY0KTNjWdWZygRxv7T4eyZhcpmmPA2LE3HDkHFxGkSW8AqkpSJIX9a3p8BbWynbsk1vgu97StOG4/Q@pKRAqLYs1MZAuaSVdqtK7Ja6I9aQs@nohYtjHo32snEL3tqI7iXQB/vNqwo9PNd0r9JUcF4UqmBnzrp6BCc0c3VXKrjXEoeF@Nq73nJdUgyIaGpB3VxZ67iG6jTMnsE/43x2FbwtNbMS3qzQEPO5OP/LZ32ns/WROaE0mACxrBZ0VLpm3yTrCkXfaH05cv3P0kBjB3/LvMem2UyN983msgADC@SCje@ZaeaQsuQ5NnSxPGPYMbGr0sOFZMJ1mQT2pxMXEvmwb3RMvoF8laScjlngghves5saF49eFPkimyZEm44wL2cJqFTn5sT1vwsBPp00oVxH/btH3OYqfxOHQe9R25etYLvdxNpdp2t3zS5fNhrYllUO4EePb/hfhTpg3ek2GYmm8ArXMD17Tq93H3qiaOSC0nHaC3Hax21vuHHjg@BOjAZ4iM@d43eGx2UHGpbWmq45gnbJdTxnYCpkWxa0h2M9/L1Mhvqz3z/vINLKrj5QxP/@vPDv7Ft2DMcbDOhTH/RGLr0oqkK7Fe/Sm9p89QqSnTnDjvrW6TdU4aiKpS006b5YxDQsr9nFXaKcs82O02h2rbuQbpiGZ1vnKX/Uh1vv1XdFylhMeYzOas8C8g4nKvJLOex/gp/DZYUuBpB4sxYYVugriwbpaEOmMjDOmy4fEEUTK@KYcKg28m2bRdrvWnwzsrwp0NByp2CEl89MoGEZ7mJZxlLNipZIT8WwWK6xlEtJSUeFXDHToPBoS8eXZpbChapYJsNfyxAK55IwCi14@RByi@VBNEBohYZuwX2Gv2bWNS1s5OzuqOPeFph8xL4FKhq@ForA3Q6e84Kb8Bzm9pxLWnRGW5ynO/lC49nQmhm2@CwrAL2Xwt1P8K2DNjYyV0645FbOuFA4racYjgWfOnygUEdLR9d61sDlb6a0l87TiYVQ0Eufn0zkVJss7maLImuZbT4/gqa7lMe@QzO4oJ0oTZztx@F1FPNcJeMizXY6IO6VHpsG9sMuU2gWrkxazBhBa6p88czsGLhQ@4nl4UrPBfxCzLxoRdOdsL8@Mlzr6yPI2TI2xF3cfI5yGN7zi7YF8J4aHav56UxBBEgKAotlovwzUzHQ6XZZXHYtF1dXBYYVQ1bIcpyJkevq0KNYEHJ@UD/YwD6t9Xx/1MLQiwbencEEt5FMyLRqzN3yaPxVfJd1KpetO1uJxOWoPxi54rMYB1q/FR6f7p@Tu3tpAXDlDQhd1jV63uIx7NBgLOhnormcGpfp6d@0ek6HfbOQZqDOgXqGavsCxnkEDfdzXDQ0tBdwIqV9zzlRHAJRuOxz30DZmhmmWLblrR7n8TxcQOR/MTO8TcHtDakn@FYffigE5XQxRZ7c3QuY7lm8o@UHzjtxRsOmicbgIIJwh0Gkau75S5dFq2Gbl@H@28p5HWgoHXvkKcORvbJVyK9sFYpsXMiH2IDFvr7/9EU8zA201Psu/dSEbuHI7U2mpqWrCeaYzLJBRVsuR2dD@72Mx/zIlGNaZ3xHnF0816VJ4vqxs6gn9HwyNL17d6VA@I/6j80mzinemfYz56ljO9AaDUBQ9o9Nvhl4ZhXI4ogY7QludwX6tO5M5oTALmmEuLZhDMwGlG9varpPW8QBPzY8Y0lTRKOG1DMMTHfyitVrmMMvaTgwZF7W2Z1F6FNzTL2O5QzD66DiNZtcWcaRupk6MjOX4w4cx@ZvkrZp@GhPV0sVaArodf9ZdBVX8c@MGCzsuc1m9eiCLyExW3y3@rK8Ds2G0@PvFQuWbIsvGDCGlummnuDmZ3LLZ5kC2pe7UoZsrpQh004TaLIXhksz@Is7IVOQ2vgD1gd1jWHTwTkyYVixdCe0Y/kOMR1sDOCrChpA@DFILKM5Esem3YVWr9/o02tpVyJUmsdmA7cUNWibv2eMbxcmHzMSe5xDy72CncG@uMJKnWex59BPid/dbM30sGapag3oRZJ66UQ6reRRbMtsvjVwPM0hek1HrWf8Ic@pZ2RcMoodqkY0vpwyaAvswpo0u64NFJqeqXjdoQnKr7dq4Ns/f2HBTMmob@L08@z8zFLV1XG7lFln8Ux7IFyHpiKO/QJZEhwBxvVDZXep5ong4f/o0ddS0AjX81n/TAIQXXfP7QPyo6EtPvfhwOeO67Wt8RHgjTsSlokTzFYOosCH1ww0bSzLBJSePerxcYlOaFFWv0XdMYWOnVSUHolrz1RM@0KhE6LGt3Pk8B1jqV08x9AzW4rYII1zEMoTf/NYEEx8F0ythmUjrgTVUpyw43xWrA1dRNxLXzKAvuV4ysClb2rgPj98cnSqDlxtca@/izs1bulxMzuu9UI6NFj1pTEMzYTytWoty/VSj040Ze/JoYoBltCbz3Uo8ME5u5nP0hFRcWqgkTKW9oLQ1/QWK4ifnj59kpju72Sxve7Q6ZvxsPfeyUkSd7187WShdzj2AdSOtjNeGv1wX9PiC9j3hU3zhsuk54KUlkE6NaE3Csz4KT@w4U7lqukMzNbpZGB@Do0nSnD3nsnnl2bymXFhdbAWsq2lhKKKyrbUfDYeWrYNnW1zGHyXlee5NUBp2aRPin@WLlRBzSGTGmYWaw@r1gLMazEsLdYofFgkLX2bWz1LgZrR6aIpZbj/UMQ0TVtG5xOjDeXKcksLazbAopnjnnNxj0lmU3RelMBJ8YCrFOvOReabSh9EdwpfOHAvHMHYWLpAZhWAwDm/sMJfmvbEsBWa5VqlXhQhNi53Wxnkm@Y9pqqCtT8XeJbrwtm/YL09izXJGL8j4dNhKMre3qPDuyIcC1quDvXJsxfsueE2jd4dAcMYm/fAeKoZfanguBUejbVQL@LbQY5HdvgYQTcpNovzXVx8X42r@mc9xmJGIhGPz54kHN5FxPfPGHiONG19gbDX12xN7HABj2DTj9hXgyczQ6Nq4m40yQdRZetXYhdKsajd4E4cuSgzsUsoOJ@LnzFVXo/h6TiAKp6hztb97SuMzkZl14waVqjJWi4NNjUV3k9YEvt6WBGSfH74fP/kdPf0xUk1XbuR42L3GkfLMCAhf1/jx5mWDLkRhID2jh82R/vfepAcnduKDbLrZ4lBpuZyVZ7J1TQ/8g7GWb8yjFSKtnGllBvAT5F5auQLtQ@dOGw/x0RxsQuvyHc/9Yia8joHLVOaUApFll6U8MBwXciW8J8/OZp8WSaDvjxhcT4YsGPHcVoiRddkdz9@ige7h09eHO8zH8EpG1xaLa9b3srw4@OQqRUTyqlt0YxwmUVFlCiUVbkcPYgCYaJqlBVp8xwd3QacC8F86uC2OxF7g8XWCT5QMBoUSuq/fCt1E1VxcVMcwkZ9pKJMUB4DsFPcEPPnv9fiR5v6G9r9o9GHfVImabuxJDa7LdnqhhSlqjZYfkA6HSVKu9qCM0ynh85LdKgtcOUl6hjz55TE6egAftq9OEbGT4gYxD8OEfvCeCQMKPIXFm5p4zi08YSWWVbGiTWG24BVtounvwPPA@sjEoD6yPb4KQhip3UE@EgNRESSrROy/BxeORQwur0GrNwwO5bNXBsUDNMrMujzU3@zyPdVKkoleiuKD5of@690vX4vFPDWkS5u6sxLvf@176U6JQbmcfoR2H5F2Npg/lVufpXCsr597Ms0/TASJtY6jjVPPKA50jt00L3N969OiYWn0/iyj1l9KJoLojQG5ynwt2IzeQonVv0cCgpYDEpJ7Fvl6ZnDWqzreYNiKoVshGP3Kq3VM8d84lwFJk@9GeF53o7tpvK5fFZLAZLKhQ@QDnDs4KYgDjAeLwLjSxfWoPy6Aey1vc1kbK/Mcr7ESzO1brzKyK8DRNchrHTZReSqDOJAlGkM8KuIaNBAJLQ4RkV5FNWiKIpaDrQc5I8tDNptQQiZxYBYnEYmngg4xhsPvOEExzRGvRYeLWQ7ocN91wUgRYPmh0xxWRJbLZ85HrDMzCZTvtUSF47wVgqnWV1@owcdQY48qN6uTdMdQv4pwqJ@qVjvOahMer7BC5et/BJBnCCIoryIZauv2Jl3ZtdSnDcZsOmPBMuGmdkG8y@nOkt4lud79/aBU7H546KQWOzhie3gMOEBZIbF9JSeSWn5@DRL2ezCLIkciWQgO7h5/hqSA9EEYqJpWl86A3d3b//wa0fPT24dqkQho/PBQJJXthNnipqs1gJDNJyt2SJ5dJA6efrowC@IKdL5kAQGfUTkRFuVk6m@jSCnKzvns7YIw/ncLcf4Jd/@NY9vRl@FGkW6hYeW/oB0aXWVckBrpOcT1wuLqJXLrUJpCi8VAr3HN7jcQjUWv7qp1rYrZ3YkepsTFlSEVxF1AysBmM7cjfUUMvvtzGHGgpt3TvHeADdcFzOL66K8nsETQXCLneecT89CEQ4hj1B@/WRAREpqyg@6tPYdcT16evaOzm8G4meHhE9MCCGcT6@ieAjUqX/JEEqR6clh4tCsruF2e1ZD8k@q4Idn@Wf8BOdm8VMmYnFJnC3LE46Ja4fGxbFKE6axOEo7gpVkq87h8uHFJajQqK89H0En77kz4GcN0sD4Y9M3HTsgfh@P@Aybyb426kO4Nn2OTRqkAMmtQGSgZDRAletPICXEMVzjBB50BulV8TAukXG138rFxnG1a45bVgdkeyyeBIn2sabVWHBUF2aajuayozKV2bQUVlbFT3DbUpjsH3Re23iKgFE1VAt69eNY9DIaL9YgfXSPXr68iMblRbxE58aJg9Ra8wfIBehvaqslieGJ2umfzrZIWmxt3ZYS4DYPmJ@X4h90vrWldl2Jrqoooy5@4g2fgBHUiFi7bwxYbGTzM2VURtbYWcxO0iEcSoUfMGWzRIK6SPAhD5VRzDaZePsdM@wJi6XKwATo6tot/Ly1BqyqqWoNzJRInK3jBQR7oHHh@QxxCfqpEKVIYMvIQtBxAIx4JVE5g0Mc9Jfw2IwhncyzwJvOY6dhPgdpQrlmlQcsdIXErOYob20VRYHOSsUtBtx3WxyqKQB7S875ujxQV@z/BppBh1aVIlNBflviRSjdCEfkU7FxHNCJhA6F8/eTM4A1PbKt2R3iL7ZvQ13BIzCKL04P6oV4SmbBBvTO0GrhWAMd6BYJOm3ilGmopqmZoNES76N9gtHwZKE63@GOB98cUIWR50RqJEyG@cvUprypaSu5XkQUpQAhs9gAiFX6dR8cHqHlz/os8Fss7H/2M7yuTY6t7@Qz9d5FIppLl@CllXIsxz5eP1OU9aqeS5cfrtcMwzuTmZHKbjy@MLvtxmEndSbLLMOyqdSGnn9zPtDyG6@q6ptxTa4Wysnz2vNz9vz5F@/q7@Ly@GIin8XYZoTtHV3LGmQgUtxkWwx/Cx@6S2nhs6yLLkcBKItEzs7wGjZ5U06lqtEa/JPva3h4uGpFrag7tXfv4tVNyNN4chbBG47Y0cNZeDFdj59YlpViZwO31YKf02U1fj9fhD@JRExhwkGpcjfWH7fJbbxrdjqjfWPC3a3ICD8Hnoj79JsvX75Ew0t62NtjEZ9DZ34axbqRizA9rf/5T9ZuklfP69t//u1@ylzDzxF@vnfzFM0nWu7jtbWPHz3KZpNAJW5@/s3n39jd3c0@TuaeV3M7WSW9tv1nf7q2puvbemqt5rpaLVo9P/9C1tNZWf3zH0frz59/3XWxWPDJMA2M@C7AT0Od6py9hee8zfCfzG9bIbOB5kb7LdMjbyPA1pEJ/dUjjNfCMmlJ4WeNaZWdzf/6g6M3ES9S0VMvh/D1Im8i@UKEG8EAtoxvu4hUItsYLH8TmaTK5TIYN//rv4P4la8BHPSZbMOrkvNh5SeRilKmKNeRSh4Mmq5Duv/3t761dMDnYRUeObupyzs1eDbo2ZbwvB8lnUrNhdYKD7QHjNle1zMd/Fj8Y8OHGSUbutvH1UQiUVMVeNQ6RUppmn5GIzVhnqKBlkjgXGLchYXcpgwiXMDvZYSYCbiJGIqbhQPxGHd4OR/u5YKn9PIX8xxLkfzaQ/NxpQKST6/oG5UEPWtnxSLRvJ5imwXZcR7iAFb0TI6y1@yJIHFFThd0OZlMPqzjXZdsjJRUxpEp2RinDIvM0DPCpjYWdoowPxqbhvnQcPv4/MX//hc//Isf0N8P6fcf8UAku2W1UxvV2Ea8dlGv8IdVKnJlKF@dkeUhSxcLxUKKfEEu1Y6Zlv7kOprLRE@wTfAff0AzEjyVCr58NNBWiXCXCjdN3YRPJbBQiGmUxeGYEEQ@USPQ4orVIUr1osYqfoYWPdWHUEyyvrkl1yp6Tj@CotNkKrgt1l13mRPxc8R24FmDP/pfW0N5ELjgew0feu/woAuetQCbu595VKVINVJNmTVsJIJAD9eKa4Vivqin6mw5oNIy6JGLsBxRN9WCqoPkUFh17ZgzfI0l/OcscefzQlXrwkgGB3@K4owjUuQX8FQkFrmCp/Zuo/puo@4nXRWVNbGt1CoJgRF81PrDWkK5uamqrxKlkvjfrgTGEj2JEkMj5KR2oyjbrwBYdRZsNOtE885DhM6B01utv9oG8Int6nbZ2aOfStVFqb2qVLdnQQjkHj5MoJh9CAAq6zUWTyTWFWWtujQPALAWY9ATgAK82b6p3FS3b262t@F/m9434guuN9u3/ukzfZaEmfrXkNHOqqnKWepMsE0N7Gqqgi5q6gwMFfhCOGiBpMg7aFbYU/6wp7YN//ATDvC18UGTTZ7cToanfiDhzF2kyAZjZlHb0DOp3Pjj/D4oVNWagv2eslLV8rkaqTRS5Bo1AKixW1Ikhf2ELd5d2CKXLdD8UhtsIzJg2mYmsgHiwWVr3F@KQD4BwBXVr9fvv/pf8Xf2/qs/YI03@PfkLf698fDvtIl/x2/wj52@xb9jD/@eNvDvuYt/p2/wb7eBf6d9/Hv0Bv@eevj3ooN/UqQMOtv6zvpOupe@SGvn2jkYLJYesnQ33dVaKEjTJktP0hOW7jtaC0wm/KXBZKXbLN1haTttaxp4gsFjaQ9Nbfh04K8NUIbwZ6XTCDx9wSCVHopnuhmAvtd1Fj@Tqiz62gR1U9XUtJq36jU8chn00FIkdXaW4j1qpmdLePLyzU29vv/scb2eoomZs6fO0fT/6Kgftq787x85T4@cvgP/R0dHT89ARakkHiaUh/CUK4lt8dmJVEo7Z0UFed@vZpHU9s5ZJaOgOZ@AmqOjW@IDnylE@FbWzqQou4Q2/7JE@kTp8qJ0WSJDYH1ZqoPZDyCCcQM4loQeAi4Q7@xlilSIS3guCC7Z0HgJnr6JG1IvL89QpYa@UvAP9Ahb/xH@rf9v/T99wWLVWhzqwNXNdoyeOP7F41c3VzfiXYnHYsIS24Y/dAA7Rrm6qaCRAl2BqRqL1@I3N9wN3rH4NgdYwTS2KxR5GhAqeyRIk9Llr9g/7hfTFs8ZngYcmuQ@Oxun0/FSwz99FCd4jGuaa4yX6FaI9UZVq/3Zj@mM2Z04BcplSyVtg3GLntVLpaxv2yyUSgXfsh6Lbd1@KukdLQ96QjYbj5dKYNnxwabBGoAtAFjfkgOopms0qfaXInHMBJcIsTSdy4yH9UflovzgQUxc8LWzG3/wQN9KX18HLoMBOGkzTvV6yxrW6@ieub6W6zLNM2/lwJ4uXF@DeIrGnWHsGd7xAAnFFI19rFcozS1nCHnfBG@mpfQpFl3DNTxvGHtrDZIyrmR05TgdwZ5OO8Oz6E@//@1vn0XLZVmRyTWrIQBMheW2t/PZSiWfBXO@AMSR16/4bQSdxJYWv1lPyZwATF6PRoSXVtiMc6EYRX8W2WY7FajTLj7s6iZCJc2yuXisMTHjV@Diu2lbW9yRZfOxQmJL/JXX4qwCrRT/wx5dJpHd2Nx4iF268ZIHBXHpyixrN@Urs4gjYjelprg5B/cPmQ8eZLaAoIV06Uyq1x/vnu7W62UZGkQZr@lg6EgiXcJLPQbDaJUGjXJbtSpmrnYWjRZLD4kZtEKORaIlEU6JQtvACltEA8lq4@ZAyDjCnP5mbc@f7O7tnyb1bWiz9YPdvaR@8uJRRENrbmon7wzaj/d3Hx@9gAjPn@zvnux/cvj5/ovn4O6yy@njS1fxnn7DpgX2S/ZS@nL41jBNwxyZZv1yNLp8w760rLoFROyNLMtyOkPmmnXTNAcQzH9K8GtarvHll8ZwQA97/6Pvvv/Rf/v@d77//ne@@/53fvjTr374Xfj9Hvy@z7/f/7dbOXz/9Kv/6Xff//bvgON/hN8fw@8nP/3qN77Ff2T/E/j955Dbn4hfKBz/SQDrV3761Q9@/NOvfvU34fevxO83b/9@7SeLfz/8zvIfxvvB764O8/1/B7/f57D8sN//be6G31vhf5uH@9XffP/r/57//5n4Q@PvvP/1P8GXsPyz3/yz//z@2/9B1wt/9m/ef/f777/zg/ff@fb773zv/Xf@qf7@N/6Nlg6/fvf9D//wr//o9//6j/5H@v89ev/@ff7f/@Y/@8v/7S//j7/8I/H7Cfz@PZh@8pf/AXj27/7wR/j/gz/8uz/@Ef7/L//67/7wX/zdr/zPZPgtbvh//tW/5e@/@bX/9Lf/8nt//ZNv/e2/@Mnf/tYf/vX/@av/12/8p7/57/7gb/6Hb6Pjb/3kr//4V/7q29/9q@/887/69ldL3t9d@f7qHu5f/QJc7o/nfeDcJ18f6vLVz4XPP4Qa01SAT4DBf/n9b/wS8Pivc9t/Dzb4D7y@F1hmfLjle1MLQPiXCyL98k@/@uc/Dmy/FASMmMXZJqOgFxIboEpvbG3RSKDvt30bCiT3PayUMyl8D6vz@x996/2P/@n7H/3W@x/9CgpuJbuV3E0q2upVZyDtldw9wmHA/H3CMd5@fPEFvMYJGkFTEmhjX4gAX3zxhTS@TkF/Jv3wGly/ICf@MO4Ffkx4@X7CHdcrhsNwY9o3rqPzdThpMGtiFHhN0umLL0lL4DexBibAd0PKZcBGqKPPhp@bhJTTfI@IgMU9xzTaP4Z/KbvFIhBpPE6MoQcEhsSYJcDrUYKVy2WKXB5TULBinDGrFCD4GAdpyggdIvE4yXoBQYwfERSIWU4cs/pGecwjJhBehSAQcuh0LGu6nCiUH0OC5fFjhrAQOIF9/bpcKZTHFQT3jlCAhBKPCCcEVk6MK@/AXiaYEE@KPH4HqBTKiUSlgAliJjmtknVKU8tR5ijvCUb5RndGyzB3HjL2sawVxFrJNSQYD43vxDT0Ds2F7ID/WWJDZIf@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@wjhuej8M1UUIFwOa26vc0o95UrhQYT0Qi5z0uVilhmwTSpcrJ/ChFOj5imp1UG3cCr7KaezWVzeiafz23qWja/lc3nChkQ2Pl0Tte1rWx2q7C1ecPYa5UVFX6XmlbIx1Wcxqg77ToemqSy11LlCzZWIRcl5Uaq9Mo90@543XVc/SCfpeUSjSISGdar6ST@6ZkMvCHJpJbbrK2t9a4UzMEZkfQKl7FAqtKVAjzLPoKHSR9J7CNwggfSwLUpTCwMOjwqidUZuK85xpdoyFoOqkZcOgNEOThpEH5KM7YBcOLV1VXoJ0XWvvlNj1Uq0GVTDg@kCIidLvOXKyhWS@2qdGF0a4QXxYNvh7GW9bmFdxqo/u3ueiatSpGbm5s2QDo8wMktsvIYLXzfNMmlAeabsSH9/88v4Nnm539UcB26Y7TKwTXrUF3jV61yy2nSfSeldrlao@trSi214bQmqutNgMFFcZajjZ7TPI/6nhZeDYfbo8opI6XW68APngN9/nI0lYru6Ju54lpqmFLpuCMWa0Md39Hzm@B4ZnPXWBtccujyatZpq9hSfaSeAvNCPL2o53M32@IQsArkCVGrICJXAr@i7djmDa4gLxptkGdXTb5MqCjruYJcqpam9s28XKrdPOybLctgZ2lcNXy1MGI@L9/44SBpE6odbUqJ9fHSDdx7UEyfpeNLIqchMqBMmErb4tyRCi17qYJ0qeENwtXatn8iSUVikq4rekbJaIqWwf87DDr@3z@8Dv86viFWRpdO8bSZZ1DcIEVt9gSPRvUcduo4dAvOI7O5JMRe16D1PXtDx3X/AWEeGfY593ps8aMwAq9PDTz@2u1bXndJiBeDPm6cMoe/MAj7/QYgiDzIAzyC17DnOIsCbLIXz5fk8mlw@BQQg58@BcGPDz/59DT0Pd3f3ftUyrNHR88ez31yIlCOPdk/OA2sm9zXj5oLQHxj/8mTeav4gMJRovG3NZbb9A2ahAsEH0CH4IEw5vJTYxqNL/neFcsNFqzxTUpF6dTf0EL1w2qYrMn3so2lMd//LBQEbXNLkgbMdi7ZZpq1nF7PwBvA2mvg2DVwob6J7XqPLqrDpC@dYa8FVcxck57inoAtDa85QiSkTwFIf9SkzYaWJ@FpGi28mwsHcRt4UfAI779b4ggfdELj0Op0PeZdOn4AqWEYDH4f@kB8M/x4qx08nga53fLp3Q4uRSTDMyKFEjCsd1Nq2aMt7cED7fkQGLxSSBeLZ@kb4LDyo/PiwBx7rjlw98dbWeA3NmIvoAYYw6Ys60WUlokU9jLZ@t/8y9/LyTJod0yW86TyaRsHLJtkdbUeMTawNDpWJQUtAo7THrMClDs/4ZEG7yVk440USKyIJsu0WjEtqQRH3yrkClsZvZAsbBWyOS2fyyU1PQnq6OYW6DxpraDlC7ktLVnIbmWyoGOBb25rU4rwtSGpDQIJ3yKAtZt4Oc823nLkqN2KFOED@@xtzIiziBHYR0w2IY6MF6tCe4PboTassqxnGXS/QdsGiAZrssjBwV764ECWH6EFZyj30rLcQkuukE5vPpJlk3z2QA/UZdnhcQq4k1n2uCWdfrQnyyMOAA8Bk@UuWvbz2KmXZQste7sHB5hOGy06xodg59yHW3q@ZROC2WjJZGhUQJbfBOAg3C5PKEuY7qMF00SfA@6zB36y/ImPTzoNEI55OA7hUz@vu7uyfMgtu7vos0cZz3FUP0PLLj2yPAQLVBFZ7oChgw2fLDfAiBVFlptgak4McMOrkPCkKNszZHnCCYQkkuUxhTaa57Jc990xmU8//dToei2zw5/JkH@BQQ/BxxqP9g8an3zS6HQaw8nu/ifH6LO396nRnoyGjU5DRGvU4XEgDvic9yfzD@B4WK8bvYU@n4GPPedTn9RNxK1uvAGcxNPBRPr1PfDZA59F0yIcGjx9CNrA51Efvo@MBvn4D/nQd9xoyCVkVNzsTfcZQp2hqwWTfaM5dEpoH5fXGIvGoslJNZ@ulciD9UFZS5du6CLDGN0Ejb1DUKuuJtVxOV0rj8ubOp9Hb8fks7Ges@TkWn9H2wJNzNjR9GxiXMRtkU47yqKKthPTHmy8jT0DjSuTLcpnOzuKXNVqO7pWKOY3X22MZDlexPdOZrP4FnprUeiS4Ste3aztgHo3jbK5mTBSenFzM166AXJ40JA2Rp5Zr8dil6ZxHo8juthLgSzwaxQnlE@r1I6Nk@Myx4pN4qVxWSvxQ0xY@hasFp6YNWp6zpBD7AC48U66SBc1ytpWQYb0U6lYPA6SiYQIfKeLTF5@/fT89PQLkFnQQRS9p@f89q@SsH7y6Z4KHSphw5Ou1APUlp2huoeCZcaHH8TkO52C5FU/hdYQNFffDReqD52euj@Gri@q3L6Hf36JKk6dUE8/nYFzAl1HnjLu8yvRFnG7aTI8CMxqMaNcAZPRYjHCihnxS2qH65VKuV7u87sWK0Gsz/i101Mwhy7HPdh9SNGvcPG28KiX0zfT8M9GffaIB6K7Y/1o9fIjaNjTJRsPwDTRus7GkbFUaeEZYY/Kj65GRRxzuCmZZRPvpJQjuDd4xy6PbNdom8/NIW62PTxaZ21mvm7isu/XZ3R75R7q5DdKZcjsGTxihlJpxGedQlYkXOzroI1wilzRDgSch7yB3k3sVbz0BmzDdRZrqY/iO9kSkPARq7M4uKVft1@3mc7y2RJd6cNiCAxqGRGPLoaMlyufAWwO@rxYBFwEE5wDWExrHfoGVot8jPjAuil1ylUMfY2vbUWWa4pSva5JlZJUgUpbmkSMsjtq0BmSLN3Q9HS@NAY3bTNb6rJGufFqXBqWB9DLZqUelLsYWuA7K4wSUA/oBHDeXrPY@1/6VnxbyZW5Y4mAXfdAmYAmvTyeFlKmXNWz@aSez@JIRD4DPy2pZ3RcIJ3U01tJXYN2GtpviA@/TbBn4QdhoBnXNRyviPViMmNyMj1Oq1pSM7Uk5Dv92mq9jifPY6CREM3iSc/Zx/swwQFZCNiWrPA14gl9oxdrOczYVoiJQY6UKJ9GsssGFrwQzrFp9Hj4uMIyG7HeegwDrZ@OBvvVWrG4Px58HbxiypudfGIznXgbj5diIDzjZdd8Q1RGsUNUGKwBU4thGOaO@tX0GuT7SqkrN1Dc3rq2qRero/WqokEG09edbbki16C4bpjQclCacEVnqqpM3fD@ZLpYlmlbeklSabqaB5QGQsIh0VjsTPY3EMWi0U09Go1HSziEuSazeElISX73LMjX6ANtRwalSS7KWzoGmErHW8hEbiTsC7PslhS5km6ubrbDg7qfscnESCi@9QFjncS6xFK0RAmUPrZGJkWt0DD3bnm3c7wrrpZmu3tSpMhYaIW3xM7EGQapNcY@dF1UYrvyin/PcPUhpCrRyTNVVqOlC6aFvSj2Oe6m22FRyJYx7Fd1PVOr6pvQJIKY9YPqulZaT6RYBJc3qhUoD/dKIpqwCF@vrgfr1VlonorW46W2E5XUmSTLJJnEopNYIYfjkSZk@F2Ey4K9K3/UpIgHnMeMIq/41Vr83TOrd1XIKLxjD8Lo5obKxF8Z/NlrPQelZDu@A/RuPBDy0GLlcjhIF0m9Hrjf1AuZp4dH9uPhgekPr2frciXC0pqCa25LReGa44Pu8lZBl/XzZIQ9jJQi7FyJakVaTcwGJ1uvNl8VXj19cfTi6ECKnK1drzk4qsr80mTv7K99HQJGM9koY2flyLicLYnlJpWKom3rbAcEO8MrhNtaXklfVzgDV8gjr4PP@1/6zex4uwB2HZTWIhRDLqFXKtqGzuKRwfuv/gC3dl/tf777hEVdY8L@/k9/rG/@/Z/@a1rHEb0puTRAuBmBkGjU8puRq6vB1dUNPNwvF6lFOFLZzTiYec9Di0yZupgyjI3NRFZ/aJdSIqy2qcUjrhIRo9ebuYh7Lbz0dAG89o64Tc7n5Hhk/9jK6drDbeQTbRGfmO5WRIoUnr6@ZgwszUqr07F0MqVSrPhOYdvvlG32Dsee3ylr7HW5gvOJGu6G8MdPNyqVCkJh0UoitRFleg78qjelWoLR@Ct08l6ZG/bG2ewsy9ka29qywd10N1zhtOFC32zDpj9zw3XB6tvMjS9dJsfYRjyVarVoNmvbZLkKlPxGCtA5i7//pd/Q9fzf/@mvXdev61@AuN/a2spreuRn2s9@BgFW7L/1@1k01IwbZdEQ9M/Ykosu1SZ0DfH20zbj4f3eGvbPGOgAVseGfjjapAtUbKhk6vxQl1aMgm3g9rwkqcl05EK8JEmBOklq8LDTTBIMtoFHDUOVlK6kj9ALWktWBlEpfTQFxfCS8l7Padbd3mg4oDH8GMXTakn2AKJACh/hCThr4i5xkreKVsKlvbeicpRdohqpOKxvui6epwMtg/QRRHkCDE/3F7GBgTtgMaRlg4BXMQjhSR6tKqRdg7R7PEKdXGOUex4gyTh2PJINqrL0ETT2RAULlABmbUOAEoiUj4AAkIeYAGzV2DbLxNmVlUiUpof13OD6T36FuNgSJ2E0hIYXzAeRSxgOnEBFxysKkC9ECYPGFXL0gXAYfLKuDEo@RicbKlG0PfbeoAAWHUURo6yxBw@mWJXLVivOKEcI/9wa4GgTlYO9GFcA5nePPm4V5SSzEwks7I9m2Q4oniB0gesUfv5RKRSVyWi9kST4vzfTIkfOFRV5lDADorx4rWgCySAykp2XYZNtl5mmb8ZZgHwTcG8SUnRQT9DnOxt/rOpf@J43gOHPIv4xnxJeGh4awRN8O7/9kkFrN8IzFvEQDi4MxLZJfswGSrFDz48dxIKsWD0KzS@bp8lC/8yeWEaLY7TpGUeEBy3v1LMM11nm4vihWBiawdfA02lEOms07N50oEDdgWPTcTa09R5XrQJHgIwSp4JwtEf2JZ7JK8qGIocxculEEOR8xJiO56FrjiguTjA2htBt9WmTZGZHZc1@i@lbLEaMRqeX2AG4OEUihBsmHiQ1dBo9sw8onZgmwxNd3GIq1QGdZtSgI1yeWsBX3QMLmhLbTYkbpVKX1rmVOsUzBRWnDVqx2BAbQTUIqx@fyxTHpfQc55z1rHOTD8zGZrYTu0zPJ0ERTQJlpz8gbBHHgPVMkqXBO8lDwW8TPpvcWEiG4q7FJvHb34y2FqtjiV5Tm2QN8baoC8MO0Zeea0n0ad2J6x9IQNvqwa4GItcUW5HLUdwFGeyxl8TRCmXa1a/i4PwgBlqafyQBGqXB0LyAEIomYRsDQrPpb@7FWgy5/YgaAKp7ULPwdCJvWMQt6YDJsBVrQtUTAt5mH7OMLtEtHXRehDjbAWBg0ZdnoYMfRMV8uF4LCkbls8MgV6B29lvgh3siBfthfJ@70UwnR03Zm60JcNjoUFplxquFb8mFLFg7kJ8p62vgmQcMF2CyFpMTADYhx2UOOog/H51zu0SypMhuQ0oyhCBIDVBIVfCvk2Ohw3Ml8HhkuPwkO3GO0eXlpUoHao2Glmq6eKCsi3fkpQYdC7RhJ@WZ/YG4usPCy5wE3KlJ4edI482JO2O6s3DrwYR/JantlsW@9Fi07UaxcbzA81I7fTqIA0/AcImhDiw6a7kZo2lrV/CfXkte@fxXRP5TCtEbBMIYghknJ8lmEoAlG83zZPuyVRIeF1QhATiUouk74vl1Q9/Sd32TNWgHIRyPFoz79kbvvOn0HNRJZD5WOk2a59APOfGtwj6wxhDJNi/Z7nBoTGLkH8fQyMCxCak9bALNPvmAEZoZdsVPVLPG1UltJvo4iA6NWjA/PMRTNqSr1UD58XroP@b@Y/Afc//xNFE/2eq4xlUydLrB7CDX4@FMfkgEM/HD3PCj6KY@BBkUa6ZxEBhyMuN2A79mmWL79OY2KMeyzxjAEwMguBlLVV@dVc9qtmtebtQSqQ4wu0yEgBIH0NUa0fSyFZiR@r2L3sBxZ5xsPJMLWiWBNzo1u4IbOK9gHoMCIsbg9LLwGKVOX@VDO1whEBkGCKiHgSeqBrtezIqXggMayRMYpypPacwRqwpkaqR9CS/hBuoSJz0nbBhQLQQI3YMsAZrgw/yaw48P96XDyyHen@qHVejE4z4e5xGtRYGSc1WFy5oSFVIIK0Xx0QSyo7pans@K7w9FUZ3zCmXzRpR/GP21D0a/DfViMfbEsLzBKEnhqmKOTVCrTVFdiKqsUg6VK2CQ2jB65hBarn2un4rWGpLZSPndDJ4OZsG9xNvSYqHCb8Z5@dCuHdmWiwErTMplyOKkzKslrxc@STnBg2iuiDbxGUHE5wIEYKQXRjNFtHE42rhc5oKDjZdEuwwhOSYkxzwKDz1egmRNRIPeU3DNJhZPDe@DB01LBngab0ZBDRrIDK9MwznoL/GoIZyWFGlOZQ5xgeAhVLGRz5q1halXQ0iHhNYcAGTEWwBa/CaSojQv8DQlsAUyipPSl1HcJtiAywpgMBLBJX4cXyxgMuoDg8IvJ6gdgLorJ6qSrOGaMvpL85@c9B39n3bbMT0bUpt1TCfn/n4hjjWkbKiChrQPLZ1FgYw9mRfictkZnSOCl3Z1HdDqGpcOiy1QtsE95d9Lm2r0nEaqb@C6D7yfILitNu73H3B@gz0cOJ7hOdlskXeaLGK7RenzPoPVsR3omoSP4QRdr@WYrh31oFCbTse2XDOJ9@Nyld2kVQj8xF8prCcLo@NKkhh65N1YBM35ClXdeh1vTKrXY67Za8eLwWG6aFWRPaNRCfu/YArFB/EkgB4NYg7e/O3F74aJJ8aKaKdW8zx2NBCeUUhkl4EMa4L@D75d0GCY60x7jnR2JarSDS9G5x13nb7TAa1v5KoSxp4DfziFjQgZgwHhkmQGdmmLoSODqZbEmkkjLqJ@9sFR2Wd6zIgH8fVZADPESLLhPI2RssMFydWXJsej@emdfDi@J2F8T1bjS73weZx517zMPT8s6UxsCgECTtHI3I0GZh3kVusWOjOoBM6oV/EI90axReuqWojpLgTdFcHVNvBHMrC5YAsQ/3wZ/VcXoB99/77FZ@A1cicTkDd9XO4XoxO/XX@@MgbBD@Moe24nF7D243umBWHxEoADVCFAjSXBZeOxe1AxB9DtdoPDoH3Ad/A8Lo@6xfe0ZqrMPRfgNLxIsnN9eRE9rrfMnjExWzERMhmC6@f4GDpsJK/ul3EUdCT0HN7Xi0HbFQ98oRlHovNAxSUsYyQv4vHlbMWDWAH30Eg5YXi4nH7of0s04xBfmY9WQz8gGsUjoOwLC4c/B5PBhJ/s2qPjp305ytsfXpK4UfluggAdxGr15DTZ@CrxeRwLsnSPFiEIq85mGQ9e9CHimYa3y/DDSHR3TqFwQ5HKfilLs6eULy5xa1WJh7jC50k@bXQ/lryL6e7NcyFW48CmImzvw5qQW5BxiUWzGQtD5C4rS8yxb8kEdKNxOntJq1JfIFCDmCTpPIu626RfxCXsGR/CFwecPocvAuyYXp0zlJ83HNMSNygw8ukbg5DWIlxASQcoISpykgs0QqEk3wzBr26CNJtL02zeSrM5k2ZQA2aTDAWSmjNJilLA4llVBD2z7S2RzuiFfWf4rBLb8NiOMcTRiquoFS1aSRa9iBZBIEfNaHE/BkI52ooWH5PBjRZPyHAeLX4Ghmndil5Hi361wABDsJLhIboLEY72ZrS4F4vfSJ5xbrp@umq0GJQphNnhVqIIkALzDVojTrHZjsimNzShYSOlMsmQY9wkdp9oHCZJvzT883sH6Pxy9MQxzg0KzBJMm2k0Qi0GTweaDf983AU1uSha8/2jA1qiFATBZBLQxwvHIfCghkeis8KII4a@NKMBX0AQ5WZxMUYs1JLdEx2ROnAoFfJs@kQ9lfSBVoz8qxC4Nk2ELpsQ8f3ymgXBC/B@eGLkZXjeQsdPjjDCOdn4ArSQqK@jKzKFZT2Liyj9cAnRWPdsILyH0Q/CS4nAhmQ66HA0OYeJDZzBLJOQL654t8JxaFCOV0rk3rloJBVEzVziTc4iZygYwpU/vio7oXiI2owIQs9qusZrWdAukCxGr6msC2mqvPIBCiGZAzXcbJ7TRR6PhZHCcXGTpLZiWTPkx@VJkuSaFZMQWcUTV0aGx1MPOq/7eA7Lh3Vf/ZhjHGuJIYBQzCAVLl@dD9DfHa6/@wq1T4S5BBYp1oub0tvq9cpWdg7z3jTZ2wWInkn2OL5QOQpSmJIcegchzXwVr91S8XHJB1fyeaIB9Dlt3ydb0Ce4g27zfQsOC7WE4cWs47kOjuf6ckLd1kh6F6qvtKiYkoDDMx5gOs3aalx5xhcVMfrQ@LbR@@ACHs4WcLjwEB5lYDhHcl7LhyObVrlM6zaIbe6CIlUrMi7Iabo0KOapI4h7mroNpm3B4ah@/Pjo2ZNvQKO7ubkZF230ZIof1locaw3acQ6ZVkMH7cGCbouexLP5cbIbh@PpztO1M1u@JUu4sAZlwIBUfPYTdTwuZFlIns/VXYjHw4YoKmCdT6uBMSOVUNUxsMm2BF09IIjpxTYMAcRXb4HeSeqtxekU@nod77ms16n5qtdx8VK9LloxLBp/Rjz@s8haauQO6QpNfoXCpcTPN2KPj9jLT3dP2emn@@zgxd5n7BtHL9jL3WenuKv5@YtHTw73GPz2n53ss@mIAj543Qx2KIGuj82mifd84XFVWX5y0p4zmHC5E9uLc/cTo88@dZomTlNtu0b/YZdbVNv0KjzWPnRHJziGadGVQn3Lw/UWdB8OdGNRuWnRjjpcvM8gbAP6tH3s8/adltW2IKyEfd@BZbr@xi7Ws6AEQd76mz@TXEnCq29o6RBdUoUrsC4hugHhce4GwBh8/RVdJWq5PILZUsXBUNPngyl4un/89ITtPnvM9o6ePT48PTx6dsIOjo7B@vwbh88@AXoenpweHz56gV4U8OnR48ODw71dcuAIpFWGO9e/HLneShRUDE5UaZ7jzDfdGBvYZke9UYNnlwbtLXRZdGSj9LGMnvXWbEVL0shF9QX3M9JUAYut7x5/8jm0@cx8gzOc/lQwrT@QX7h0BdN6mm1TalBZKlDfSqK6QrOnaHGaj@hPGJ7IbpZoD3qMzEnmA6dFPC3LZPIerlHBsW@@VZ3qsg8aEloD2AjKX7BSZnSTQjSa3CaQFUit2XPwdDqeGl9EKCwY9aG/1KQkEcXEWhkEipsPDm0cD9JKgQPwPTjoIllvyAOwTODAA7Asd0BV9BDXjrCcCDHyjkYonlmeO3zZHxzQtDDbDBweGdSLLQiceLlRkRosuIkGN@736L4MPspD93gZbtOyKIpL4fEuiV6PVwyT32IEMpFPJdLaNggpg7Bp41SDWPbGL/BDX@AGXCdktD2XxcpxlZ3i4iDTtvhNJZ2eYfMlUNOlO8R7rIDHq5TFAlsruOGjxa98JwbE24Vm8QjiPRZaoXnfeBDz0a0UDbFGkm7Z8peg3YXAo1sI/DxgAJAy09NpUktFW0gRjNMWrBxzHeBIHLd9Fw4P7NwaNc2ZCGLVVuxL6@3buCBycqaf5K9TJOygiN6aQ1AraSqz7QyhjpNYpTsRUAo2u87As3gZxmZzQDNO1MxBaGzYILXX5cpMakiH@RRtxw4l2gAuXpJqA5jyPqkSx/O580B8TS/IA86HRpivu0N0jAbemDqdO0viJNKlicMvoAjTXDkOfk48woTrn9JUdrxjeMdWoVx5/OhMefc6iRdtcbHA77bzFx3iDxgT04LqQfN8tGBxiHqXqGn@BSnuqIGxxRo8IS2xlvvAoB/YtaBf97BeCvz4cuPb7rjnZd6dHK@vyzyWgpJJXHfodmNT6ZZkVT/JJMWpMbEEJCQ7AVmQ9THfJUkwA3n9EHe3YCmUgCI2yhHst89dPyJEiJ@7xqgNkkXcAieKO4AfZxVaUTG9FBN3tYTLI/Uq9qicqMRT0wUlLETOmC@ikz5kLR4PLUuh9uoWuMerwYH8vj@4wkrsePPwQdAer4T2QbgpieWweLMUgnV/sO9WgOWN288FFvKeXA6YN5K3oQWcHjBncj0SrKZdneLrW2VHdQ/AYNuLIygB0FBqI5umqP2DYWM8QjwMZqoQnZw@3j8@ZjLvn0BckHvYZWgJMYiw19jz6WpbyyZhpwZKU9BZDpQn32VmRZv/rKrMC4m3RFQIHSQp6BEIi@n1r21rzKWeaFlIhaDV9yQQfcrNYnflyyC3KgDfQB8QkJ0WWiiD0sJsRnjjY7nhReCCbkmuG4fX8NMKa952491qw0kYUHhNkNHBnSWLy@8l14@LfjpcwTLfjCjDLdCkob2BfsIJ3pAOAVV1tgRXFItfpLjInivYEZ92uPArPath/8MZihiJK@FcFw6JdaEcC9S4frzuqzm0IBGbAQNXegpPvqIZPHwRTy7b4QKNTxu92GwTBEom3rb1MMwVEL12Uwqufo5N28lyoJCH69o6YVP1sazh6KyAXVoe6GNcC52fFw/zSYG0XZmU8o@TFG8lZlLyab4wM74nQM7ncpm7YM/nwo@u/ENh8zZkXn56/QH076cg3YlLw/vAuYfPkr7/lAFWkI4vrfcrzFxEUHUWtCkzeafGKIwf4MLHhQAZPKcZLzCbTzXOxnO4LYbOW6QwdApyKw@hKhxklNeaW9S/WZ0cCuQ701v78PR4ZcNAuHTwBlflP3WGrjndlRc6NiXkhNtWZ93M4dCmYHw/Ux@hxGgb08rNdrTbji945blCT5pvC@ekLXYn8WW3SX@sgRKh4UUV7yzE0b3S/PCeopXCWT04fLLPNuiou/bMWKQ8lOMh2bNm2asQIBlM4xLYfNAevo/dIvwAh6QPEshEu/liRJv4nbgRRUBrrtK9F2JZqJCt2nzpt92mYeMZHkn5Y5fJyQcQkUZh948O4otG1tOlmfiAnDuwYxArKSuqTFHBDQd0EdIsCF6a6B5qsHCnhr9ScsVN00ZKK6TzWxLlzk56yX51q5bcaJZlBo2vYffd0fCydd5xuhdt1mODLxvj5uTtG8ZyWZaBtPQH/KhSLV/GneMxtgnvAttKE@cKBHfo3q8zmTGVjhbFiWU27YeX1licDNRpLuIOiTkuZRt9nwtxi51X7lfztbJdTpf6VbtWwk1@XqLsJbREDB0eQCsKMobPzFe9Grap4VFX076gm@rptiqxNYTR1hBweWoMLefJ7rNPZkbjUAHAITCx1psG1Pl9hR/hajbce6La5mVMDJMlGXKshAqS9BHtCtJwwzqNJ@NwTMsCzKBUkqDNumN6T@LSR2l1NPAc8hEJKcha7Nq6lj7ytzGlaUQBglStmo/ONsGZhonhxBB3nfBV1IrG1TUN907GQyCqGJPEoXwmy7inEBEVe7mqNclVTaPZRSTwgs5risa2t@m6TmA1V6VRPFzKYQxpw0S6hkacAIHPgGYbMAnS3F3a9iFB9tGuoYG70BiVR/tkaIG8RJoi@uDyb3ZF@5so/jYQgBP@I65zqWKIU2heoEjyvYM0uIDnjM12/HGaAbdV8kL5CDOLsHl65SlwWilONMJkBZnA/aNLJCenFTwiB4pGtlvZCMLHeXAiCc1TC5uLtKQiJa8KfnrTaLFQNMWP5gcOkeKjO6mBI13QPXpqQrWasD2z1wOkOS0@mpIDjbS/V6SfCNJ3q5hmLUCe@yu3/JUZf5X7c6SmoVRo4KeBiuFAcuRqGu6GydNgyVtplRkpLyqUdFMFlWQatrQqrKt6Tt2aBq4ERcm5MvDYnvFQQj6vFpQ@91mbiRMweOBf5f6Cv3VR8gGWM2EfzqaPX0kUkEmLZ8VakzkuVW2rt8MbrcAH2UwGajLGo2N5E9vxSin2YApxAhocjvNTta2Up1ASmi9xqM7Ile2HsiqUjJ3YPBp8F@OtirWgjoSoRGkmiHBj2rAI6ZD3WggEwURGY37NrfiRJyLyJAQWQ635yfJdkLcqOGRtvoqXcV/kNb78yj6LnB8ustjzI475@P8t7uq22ka29HX0FBWbBInYlk0CIRiTNsYk7uHv2AbCAuIWtmw0bWy3ZcDuhFln5mJeYOZ@HmFe5bzDuZqnOLN/qkolYRJ6Za3TXGBJVbVr165dv3vXV1x4Pt0cFxB1us9T88UU703wuAh/lIX6xigS5T1LUpzfSewbu8A6T5/PYHdxG/y57ifMjkL1FA/krkOkpKMIBaW@j1UhBt5b/3CXrA8ezLFHfX8qyrjM8OgUlhU74I54siFiNRGSTHgzGvXR6kgTvjs6Qi0hQpZX0NwSUTRG9pxVQ88ejp/BJ3kgHRLlxAFSvkMHkSggvOnh7eRo2EGIJuhaccclmOSs8mDGGxrQZl4v8zFzX9yEbDWF1X7PZIJrjlsPSjoceW0/Z8EcLYTZj8VF7XL7lvvpeG4E4cJgSFu3rL/cBO1fKx/Qnvu2kH9dMER2K83B@dzrN9EBKxCSCljOwzR2pfDGsgzbcJttw1kkmBG7ONAfg276t/5g4FtlGDEoYgiT1tAf3/qdnGXVfW0ERrqoymiZxHPYw5txmzd3YNLlgTLiKeEww@Yw0DD8xfGZzcVtspVlLDRaRdZmqOrboIMCVCdOukO0DpPBAmECWB6Y6NqfgFCWHBFniWzPkheau1zjRhRIA3FODNuEFsNgOAnaUDO0k2X1gRSbQaLMBp0EJ5Bfu@/h4eDcPAbweEwkAcWAMiV9iwdLGs3/EA9CFkzZ2D1VMy70fkNqK9Dc/XEAvW8kYKoVSmbwDhXc/FhriMbBTvOkXK8KeD6sHxzXtqvbYuuUbNxoKCfAWvHxYBd6F21NZ6v5AXxIlRuQMkUBVnn/VFQ/HdarjYY4qIva3uFuDagB@Xp5v1mrNjKitl/ZPdom6ztQEPsHTbFb26s1IVrzIEO5qmRWlE4c7Ii9ar3yEV7LW7XdWvOUctypNfcxM7Tql8Vhud6sVY52y3VxeFQ/PGhUBRbM2q41Krvl2l51Owf5Q56ielzdb4rGx/LubqKgByf71bogJwGjlFtV4LK8BUtYzInKuV2rVytNLFD0VAHhAYO7GdE4rFZq@FD9VIXilOunGUm0Uf3LEUSCQLFd3it/gMJZ9nekAvVSOapX95BpkETjaKvRrDWPmlXx4eBgm2TdqNaPa5Vqoyis3YMGCeyoUc0IvMuLsgYaIC0Ih@eto0aN5Fbbb8KYcXSI/g4OVPIJCAa4LEPSbRIwukFgaUFIB/VTpIpyoArIiJOPVfheR5mStMooBfSoqDTNaJAhCLFpFlPsVz/s1j5U9ytVDD5AMie1RtWBCqs1MEINHTJOQXUg0yMqNdYT8MWPoKyW0twMVaeo7Yjy9nENOZexQQMaNaktJLbKRynzHMLfGpsowRD3DLxrc2Ol@/DTrY9okg93ZObv0WjEpMrBdhVGZAlWlYoCjmDUWUtAKZlhMNLoQHiNQdZ0/MubXisYdId4xlQn442P67CXwXtJHLzu4dz6xmUgcn@FEqTTrdZxuQUL3Uar5WSekjLGxvdSyG3wb8VyZBkR6x5X3rjxs77Oct@ICWrzpTR0kqMeGiAwJkv/Jbu@ede@I1y348tkeHgfCauto5DNJldoSoGukQ474gUVUZa0M0HvgVQHSmgr8rl2C/dJ0TOSIg1D@Df4Gr3w4GB8gN6Zt7tcFxexxEbwu6@y4UwIEoH@SUSCoEtZ5kLf/7Vn583scM2f6w2HHdtxVBqKO4F1YM92vpP80u8lkmeT6YlZMjtLePxQrbtpCqPtz1JkQtZLbkwls/Ffa0I/juKGMR9w15Syos1quWlpv@Tk6JGUERLaAo9XUCXjnG@v/Kl2gqu5/PKbYuL7R/2d2xb6CyLqLAx4Z5Tugn4@XnAEaGCExQEiCSRChusaaZS/iY58BxGvMBLdH0Bj9ZVP4zqIBCayN17fzBNH43EwNbmHfvhDvby3dbSzA10ncvtmbeXtatHSsFufMvx7ivkQbCuhjo1gHId5GgUZraQCEx9qKQZ4dqT@pMCuixERPF1VGn1EnAfttxH3ZMKODIsb4m0tA3TRS/koh5QgAI7nltLXuS1TKoAdK6qDpbn2pjTF92CuRDognVn6M6q1Kf5D2rr5qyauCyQVSKoYgeWC5sLqgvq91I5yFaXFDQH3YJRcSukxw7hpGdBWF/nP4ulaepO6bdRiyK6M2F6p2iklMPE8yYVQfhUDbtmHhDMiN4AJPQy@fJL6Bo@nEuCO4O68cFKeNECMOzol7lNHm9Gy0GeS8sVmCaro5Uud04bAXX5HMkVtT24na2AQozUQKxfoVFgSCcJFjSOSzJI8YH9adMQX1lQE70A6Ramx8h00d15xJJWiwg@R7wqVQjAtDXLCUrvTeVgqyqnGsVDijInph@RB9P9EmcyhvwErTqAeScsAAXySJIkqywqWrySU4E4ZGgzrRiRN89NpROberJgrXTBpvZny@RoQgaydmfpwSrCHXXuOAFDJcWPDbL/aJe3Kg6XTTylHJkc7yaB9PbKFHCvUUPGAbnb1IkPTroyyreCLIxzeazIy3IWk4ideuF1Sq4clU2IpL16EKSbnKPwPd4k2QHSDJy29Yq/VpGblZStT/YCEWjIGnI5GTIJp6f2jVrslYUBkxvp@aflSggLSm8jPw3LSrR5Dwe65ccRFvg@rSSh4iO@Ny2QcfCRk3SU5YvZ9pPOiQ5shePHH5A4HiD5TJ6i@iJqwX5CjCGYSeR1GOIPY3To5EC0Nq3eae9qZRA3V3B8NGHne510tFSPHAB@SQ/O4fE7seTNguf@0YrOKuUuNYQZ9FzEz3paQ6fGSk/ZwOIapo4flBh4zwczJiRO56eAPwpuxxC@E8SwYyx0JNemHbHDaxKt3GmYYkJ1YC4MJnlbo5Eg/qEjXPnqIMjzJNLsqbFBepaObatMxmL4qCHsjCtkAmRAsKQlxQ6yKr185FgtUQob6JMEg1IsL8tmkfNDuoJvf3XD8K479OAUadPyORiY1SNJeIFdSbUAYj@0JF300DGlHA6oCd0C0JAq8kaYdVWGMfivVSfo1pSJ0TMQupZL88Xy0kipvKcgoUlyZOyjfahYqE6W0LKFBNVhoYXmFWJm34Lp/dDFGaKFxs7VInQ90l7LOk4jSCzV1xCfuN/XTKT7JTf7SixBbD3xBG7ecgiLDOGdFu@rDfo74Q5@Ck8Afd8w9UZjJdLwRbr/R0mc4IF1UW4cS9q/tTUJ/BiuAthtMXaLRsn8eXg1alWHf6wXDwIN1GsKyT7nHw8cZPWKF9cbDu5Du76GAjhGpM4ueGV@GYdjwXdsliwY0VzjxR7bppjAZz8pXDBNBO@foBCj0eEX6PUpipOk0b1aiRFb8/Cn54xWc4qNpXxfmJWaLPhKQHdxmwoOCz5BO6GCScfi0@CDC5bciGDxeiqzwnEc89mIcvwMRkRkmxrFi5oFbglkIXJk9yvFZZ5rpEAbhGIGW/G0f75gJbfqc8fAKWuhF3qOnwLoorOWNpGxFmSIOIT7MHhf38ts/mXtg4AfYL7yepy3zFIG6uK5CWwp5vSJRRoEXcg8MqI@mnhh6saAHo1A/RrQ1TVKNB88ekwZ5/sCkSMLsPdBKbJE2LHzwSji7BV1Oa@bgoLIoFh3C7cApSHli5x9XWP97/rPU@NGIyztn2DFVJGXbYPoxUbVBSnhTZ8K91mSZMZW/32KWl59aawkBlua5nBn3udopNXOhEygBj69o1hqOoTNOJaQnXT0Ww8lwtPhE6T3ad8xFZpsn67bjfNcRmJWtBIPlUodEW5rh46xoJflJKE1cYuRpBjqEy1d61mqeFOK01ML2VmrNviOHx2QW@U3pQUXXd4fbPg6Kt@jRqwYa3aSIdwQpLervZy0oeOvxHkTS5OVVi3qMFnYZrRk/GqQSYtJSerqESPsk7wl5dEBymG8HZGfWz6NCTTrJKchTFRQDuUR5InA7HtqEfmnURecLhInjGa7upPSEc5qZkSmvkL1EkGEMYII4K/az0T4U7@BGlZXQI7odoGu30FuogD0RPG2aHg4a9F8LjFD55eaO9HhozbKFiyJTmmpKsKqgWN@ipM6bw@tZa0pUHogCmvgcUegSPeibrp5eqh8tC8QDCpyagqWnbz6DhXHEK@AG/plBrSnOgaOsZMpYi4o3hBZ1DdAWYJXS6/u8XMXZXzBmjUfvBtmMYAHBn238eSVTIJz3al5LG5NMOzOM4khxc2tzRHaTk0QKxe8oftkUeapLC1cg4DPHkL5UAAoIa0rco1GAoHdMzYsxKusIEpYK2CzhI6GiRn6ec8JRqDLCmxUjRn5ejHcmjexcIjCxmB8nYgTmLPOjRFRgoJvLixHj7fzyRDFgQqx0nyUOVSFrJS5DXXMsQHgkbnWPclYQmbzUYAp8s@LEArV@U@i7vBGaT4aCfDSHZ9lCMnQtHwuNZbu8HE8aSwnycMxcY4EgCsdkWPcKP/ZHR1NMyHPtE2osMmKzDOmfPcCl1B2u23L/GooNOpSt5hiKnnkyXC2/WnzFSgyU/dsA7ELi/hd/vLDKMVUxIq8KIFg6ddbF5vUgTVhTONJjqXChq4D2ND6BWtIOu@K4ubMTQ329nCk/o2t/vJLP51GHL03se@VajTtJwdCNx3a7N/2@O7r7eXx86VLXjzfa98PhulpA@1Aj0CbC3HDc44shkAeIirGz8hwrLvVvul3zBgY0UGLdQa1xTAmGIGj8CbTPy3GT9n@IpBxff8ECYvl@Ebrx3Xk8z5RUlBUKUqNH8G1KGc9APPihi@7Z2lBFxLBfVs5MMGw5pc0vOIDgxSZUWYRe7HyJvJNTH/1@f5gRJ3gBMAIFPLtPJtjZMRPkOQoaGOlw701IcLQZ4d8GfeNYMUYxVR3JqXFJXTOhYOERGr/u96rTkZ06@5yCUQWK/AqL@QrhqTMi1Us5Eiv@CWRZD4HtJ8W@9kZ2m@SUjAwjvWzA0RNw9LqQmbv0iUVxaEtMyuz7sVGo89nNEVYDFN2hqYCCsqfqpZI8El0LN3U@LXRRhnmmIXlCyJWnpcCTZn9er3g76Xaf1inSLQBcsf/0DpFMANQCZfMDeSKI9r9koVnvJPBEeH6Dd3U87HcwQQsTWNaLdum3O7tcLouF0atXolzegodsVpS3ymIbP2xtiW1438L3l6XllZUi97nbzhf4uKU@3ostoEEbnK/aV@NteIWwEh4bQ2dtrOIFt7SQKS60ShubxdA9K2/hqX54@vu//@ff/@O/3LJ8@R982aKXs886Ui6XcxfaXxZe3hfx/Wz7YnHh8mxhdLHYK6KW/YNAw4e1SdaLvEdz40srzaOA8ZXcSNUym8BnZFKhrvO79sa/Qu@yLtLt0E3LryFfHEV9bLrtG999PEZ5CSt4dedAciUPTKSB6Ax346F22j7638F4A5IEXtANlNOzaUXt2yMajI6gjSppCcRDU9ZbH4@0REAKeBQXRqxsMAj9AW6A39KUl4tnWR78BpOW1F/3817Y2xpOxdK5LZbyYikjllIp@imsvoOvzoIb4OFcjgargVQqAyGRZQG9DEUY0DyPlg901U5C3Ja1QDf2ICWFUkGR@RBcRi/@6KwM37cW9qxneF@m4B0SsjFhkvSXhcE9VMsXiHGfip20oYlCSy5iKDPDoKLrF2dAXsh@AFHO1yyQ9SFkiYY@OpCMT676IuvaosuEiDCKtf5hh9o9foCxaGEgXZ5jSym85Yi85/krjo1FPgtNbGMI5x8xQPYUXk3m6SDhYnrRYidvo5RUTD6EbZZPKh@7Osz8iXJN50T/JgwlYGduU3ALA3msRfpxs3VFpAJtXTGySiVdv4VlJLm@6U@CkTytQLljg/qic7vnloQ1SoSYDkP2rz9sYbRPoICiEtXCd2XNRGeIReeWMJAn06GCnRwbjgwhuJ9taNtfE23bcemQiFIH1gFiSnvydb2gH0rQlTEJu@eNL/FyQK9L96lN2GxG23l4x2mC42FXM50jyuRxHrVnKEp6NPZ6115GpPeHzbE3q8GwBTOfSTvnQAkRgQmZwMYns55XPMUwl0hWCUlEF4Uch/Dugv5M3o7GdZvSR06wSlVTkKgr2Ahi6kSS9L/G6iohx0ir/0AlmCw/6Ly1MVJ2sdTzoqORpJQyT81QM3vQdCyVg9l2dMNJWcyqbplKF2SiGxxor8nuCz15HyECZN4peQhQnkRYfYf54@jU8wdebHAa9S11zt8tCh4XsT3TTZTsjGSpK08L0YV3yBXMIz/HQSB4bFJoRtYz2352Hsrb3NLmOEIY39oV3/VEoO@fo/vL6GCIOBoE3FkmRqjoCoycqJHjP1Do9r0e8De782aoiudp@/1z1zn7fD64WLLPB1/Pf3eIE9klq1E2K9LSlq16LNlWYGR0M7FX5ZQWKqTB80E8wvlA8BEWQwTAiGuffXYvvrrA0Hka75A/T7NAYlWGnLjfzs9F8u4DNtNxLty09cxZclTl2@8LjoCxlX6xDvmDw7/AhVpU0i49rHPGXSBFx3R/u@ETJ6G7tpx/s1x4Ayuhnj/Njv0bHG@z4c2lP4WpRIjLWRh6zn@PaUNMEPfT0CvCxymUk2814aMnoTyjJLtQ2cwpH0urFaTJsU5AfJAyoaXiCRdHx/HQ9ogughkBKqfiEhQUew4a2mfj@BkOrzEfL8R@LXk4hDUSnQzYRYR2ULNIWd298piGOqq5LNIxp5yoIHQrEYHqddPGaDEYDrJysubkFos4icZDM/21/Fo@2UYfNNFYC12Qk6nF56Kw@f7t3/774Lf0JL257J6M4XeS/i29upbmR3iAt9fq7Ta9md7AaKv36ZkLa2B4fPu3/4X0mz8DHQyZbcC/zRVFa3WW3syWKMnX9OYqPBSWlyHf//vrX6EMC7xiw6tYF1oZQYwVlUQq3oB0F8JFDUvJy9LFqFuhc1lIgx0MYW0OL@gXNV1ey9MuXVo6Vdz6EvhKuaPIIZ78sibkKcQ7GcqdAmZGnKCEGWSZpPKg6ArDdUN5baDyRmyKX17kVkNYAfwivTl0ltpz40WIHkMLvCyCCrQ5R1jP88Nm/n1Ke3esp5RLSVFNIXFpJ/vatdfF/wc)

J-uby is separated from Ruby 2.5 with [`defined?A`](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby/blob/master/func.rb#L334).

Answer (score 2):

## 293. [Sardonyx](https://github.com/SardonyxLang/Sardonyx), 13690 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                         @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111111      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[#[/e]]   >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#- [!R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#~  n MMMMMMM MnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###
#|9999 9 9
#/9 999 99 9999 9
#9"" /* *#p 173#*
#cs !9 9999
#<<<#
#{   
#>   
#    
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0v01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10v 0v0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
### \MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' wWWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;_W;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@]]]]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__=""" " 
#  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99]]]]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"      !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp         ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa















































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;mint};dnu1&&1&Prers>80::\0}ngt=Bk:pextsepsEx94 Cr u Uitharc""2:body+/+--- $在 16 5""61*F 4, _._#a*een gi>/=[]R 8ogrputs34ui
ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ f e`catch`\ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a )where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _ )=r$0`f`f 2 64;class (Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$  (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"]]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>           K yya+-        &  g+$
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@    A=AgRA;       AC
#:  /          
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;$+/ #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/
endif #@[[[["272"?]]]]* * * * * *<
#<<<##>\
"""#";   print(85)
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOprint("65")#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyNLdiD2@db6RyQLvA2AQBVQhQfxINDNZpP3cm53s4dk374zIBpdAApAXQJVaFSBBJpkx8ysPdas5LU8O6sYjbS6o1lrLVkbsfKG1xp5pd0I6euGYj/pB7QeDofCofkH43NOZhUKIAB2j6QIf3CRqMrnyZMnT548@W4abu/nP4/gw545/Wm373jMM12PtUfWhTlS2cMpe2BYbk7PSBKG2h11xwPT9tySFGEaY65njDzWN@zu2OiaLAKuOpvZO1bfM0dJ5poma5p95xL8M4zZ5iU7tFtWGyAxzzk3beuNOQK/LGOPzP714NpjLWcwMOy2y4Yjy/bIN8fYMwMsnXHrnBlN1xsZLc9ybPDKM/bc7huDZttgFHw4MnmkbQagWucUZ96nwNgTZ@SakILTMl3XQcciOBojy3m8@/SThfBamn1iAFLDvjlZSF7T2AvLHLUXY@js89ODg0XXDPtMcWx2cBslLct2x55z6C3Cz7HdrmkbTFeLqr7omQdiema/kC6k57zA78AaQWkaotRKs5Kxx4OmOQLiiyK8tLyeChFOHU5w5tj9KTMnAAxw7EAw02MWlhbLpdMYEv5PzJZjt2fgwckEOADXHAy9KVOY7QgeAC9nxNyh0TKVttm3BpZntlnfAuycjsDGZVDg7NycXjojKHiFsyIh4g7NltWxMIrIgSshsz0ym@Muc8becAzouaxtuUazD8GaU9Y2O8a47yVZE/yAeOR@2TNtgZJldzEfL2YuCMGGKsCx39SANla/zwCdc0QHk3bZDnpcojsGbZqEpdlGUPszcgEko@/6uZ9PeC4ZjPds5HRHxgAYtW0SDT4/fMbcljMCG/wwLK8F68C0DI/t7LDo/tNHUVYNyKiOmlJA0gq7YoxFfE92YfTHpssGxhTStj2oXMyh8vNjSBCcRTeiJRbNZJieZtksy0JlKzA9l2ZQJYpggFqrZzT45ZleYFkN@D4XTWI6nZHRtfomh9J1@h0EtI0cq@eYDu90Nprkvi1KY5tlCiy/zbZzbBveRVbUIRGEmGVaMQe/PPwAQhEw0OCXyfKUArZAdoIssD3WMQZWf8qhD4cIvsVyGtsGiICmBpD1AkAo6ghh/gnD83pA2J5xASCVvnWO4sIMJAaWVgo@qa2tFIkslI08Sbdn9vuYKhAKSJQrsG1INQ@ZzkLKQEe9oPuZ7/Yo@4TXdhp@gOM25LgA5E0DpdJIqm34gR3EkA7yRgfhooO80DVw18GcQagQLg9@eSirfEBavU20BekKcTUkJgoUDWkA0RgUXSbLoPCyULwZLN5chgGegMB2noFMKWiskGWFbQbkKqYZkF4DZLDsNZBlGiChITAoUg3KVANENGAWDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9eLM9YC3PQcZDKXIZ7T81B42@AHxNIBVx24RQds9QL4Y9wCEK6ALLntE8LoD3sG0gJKABkZWA0IkgOcCDaEB7O@neEsRaGbpme1pBsJahVvAcMSx5ceKAFAmjCDYQMKDDjjnlggAeMgkOaF1dg1@8BFIENaBpiRbaG2o@Tw4VieinIWminTucCGlKr/XDIuiYjmCFtRkFdtczRiGBYaWzdJwsQdN13z9Rjb2hleHZBOJgjWjmH1AwSo6hgetQPwjbqQ3nQe7c7IGVD9GqCw6DvOcIXYBdF0iYA@dS7NGeozyWUMh32Q5@BuAiHGRh@QuTRIHyB1IZwqRwgiYbxWzwKAlBTIVWtktoj2IusQOwMSeB7FEtOr9zII5WGoWciwoQNC1cU49rjfL0FzZ7ZYpppqmxcpdOFNx3yTgTj4jQm0hwJE04C2nBpTxCKAdE9XqZk69UvWdQbzWePi5TDIes/CJqB/aUyh9DogWcyJMQCNg2GzbkPDPQCO4SWIJeHyhueQtR076gVQLkfQvEKmg5wAyD7RxLMGJuhjDkTBEs8S0ijcCLPmFFiZqJVVSR3jmCwQSpUWCcUdsiEHXlmgYWuPW0g1TNuyiYOgQXCptaoCXK50qmiAKjcyjTYPhtoFYhTSj6C1M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbBW3HVZmFaiEwfNfpAI9REw2qBkSdpdOivGPOA6eJ2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4ZuIN@AmgdpAvQxjpfWuwNePZ7Luu3xqPRlE2GUADWAEJ5LafTAaZ9Yw57AIIN2qw1bUGtNDyp7ZDwaQ0XchvYNk0IY5uQ471n32BdEwgNjXEHkCQmn@E@HBL2RAXD5g21bQCREPvWcEoUATBBjI7jqOjedkyX2AMUmaCyY2Ku2aXKADWrMxM/A1Q8gC9BGbCBW0HWiAqF8DFBaWlmMClR7p@YNlSWFvAhVHMoOVRFd1kH1P5QO416ndFqmUNPcIZDAsyyQ7rM0QHqMuSqCGCq25M2H4AaNoeBBEEln2lCjbdxTnIVdXxSsQyUrqJvAc25bQbaK@OypD@9lTyEuFhIXX6FYeYweCWvwGFIlQAVOxILYw@FB8pDq9VD6eehfCEFA@rXaHw7@@AWTn40YEonSBux0UDQSGoqcEI8VsNQ4Ne/DUgd9hFWdc4Bg8453AHacAdLIDsBkv122FVNGSqIwbuADhzbWQIViBnAxSDzPlQWxIwnKDCMfsCMVF3cuTJCET3r9mLTBa3mcOiMoGZweTNFIcaLLMRdDu@ixILWIQ5d5vnGFBqJKDbxnse7W8M@dIGoimFNBVXSACEB8osr/yDuHJ5iCGGq9QRL4HdJwp4zE7Setm2iNmqMphwIZA8aZEhoyqzRCCTgBTYLvNXxmw@V@BRaAaPdRqGK5KB6v5i4ihy9N25ak8UeRgsd1S9d6cIYsQ52LkagZkAlikU7bjReJneKGfKSU87QS1FU/pYhIAVSochjHeivQBtwAILmZGq3YvJcFZOTTB57nYIcBwNG5FoZ@5ox9Bax@xLckGkG51CvyVZmXWiwFQXeCroRJuiRUtHDGIFmAZUQFOxisd002DVIjxFTJnsUGzVC@mpqNkjLtNtBWoIQiEs4vypPwh21yKCEGjTMAQannFMjMUfA96QERZTBIZUSTSc6kH7H/UiT4Y5jm0YGWIwrH3F2FWjn0ADECBkL1A2rZXkNoaDcu@erKhuVCjAb6E8gNtvxsF7vD6GoIKkhsEr6h0hE9ZwTD@tGLA75xcA3HBtQlIBTK1V25fVGUOPIfiNBICCrZCMn@4QV5fzUOh@3FwvaRkcMJGOtAzXJanlyWYJ2n9eGyjqqRueoCnp/FKmKzIvxCfQt5iVXLFBZBBuZLiq8FYFKqIRjiIHg1aUk4lGF24yh96atvlAJuAkqO5dGTUD/XHTSA0GUFDqBX2lv1VQOBKsDh8Oe7Z5@WhF1kXummpZdmnPoOy2jT86bGFz24z4@fHi8e/yNxhIYfatZWnRIWdlCHpva8UTp2uNUVtVLm2EYM8CPGuthY8T5MLIkvJniTEKq0rQFjcvEJ@fR8WeLJAFNCMlBKYAZfwsqDQ8DSpfUNNzeQiPMuokEJBlE8cMy5ZD5MAMDoo7@ho/Ps/GbN1h4i0gNhTti1h8bHIDvmDq0/Xgqei4oYL5Xs8NbRIoLCqhl49DnzBQO6ePzCSrMi8iQFh1imU@ODvaPKwS2Z7jnZr@vUJCU64EuZYzaKvB8f9w2pWVhQPyBqcUS6gxxVKUJ16UEbrXmCDwrW7YCPgDA3o3qMKU/8LPm9gD3vcW8kavSCjiA7ARhUa8M60OtD0U0hAc2cS3s5C5rRclj1lgFTktbrMB3vtlq5XLmdrYYbrZaszTbYaADUootx9cbR@B17iroos60SKFWC/RPHt9C3CUlEroCio@Z22cqpeX2Jey9KBaLuqk96Jw5fVN9QRJPZnI8lYr6Y55qy6XuZij8/sTyYuk4/2pxCAup7@4e6o/8wGKMjsYuqNOAvW9smUYdnGNoucAjttN3ug7bgjhcO/QTBLVpZTZ3u459q4QMdMSsRnDSAuQvDtUYQ2hrrDfUZ6RY4Z4qn/AwbPcSpLSWzyCRiEIEKkXh1S@NCwPINcv3yeE396ER0XLpdGBO0wMkCMUhcqGpFXIlB6ZAQqrAZ2kGgwmMW7Xd91BCMwiYaSHogoi7M@@ljiQx1dTS8EtQ4rNKoTCoUKM6bjlRl4bgUGbh2Ic7hEabho5aWAIudvs94Hw@SMPHFzzQp7EAoFsVxVExw@VjDxBJzCX48UEPCyDQGFswvmQHcyhQMhSLVG/okoPqjYMgvdngASr0wHGQIOGEHQuQDjaNBXZB4EJknpFdnhGeErnMZ@kcuhw2QmuarKA0LY8P3TnjEY7RW@1w3iB4RudhABplLlRmNJgPfXw@eMIjUy5AwTNA/QclH7oJIDlpOMqkLBh8IgD1PBfHn6DrklZwPBTgK@zBXs@wWybvCyoDVJCYMtxnUW@U2lW@mTKUN8Cga@QmZn43PC9FhX7qE4BGGYKJKeoBidENkjzOgAK9oL4Uej70mzJpOPV6kGOlxWSj4gxNe1Gf49peLF6m6ZNoVP3SsezYVXRjYyNailajSTDdB9MOmu6jKQGm@2RSyIThVDRRjCSZ0LdGMdCtHr2p@ZAn8TrywASlwhtrGDNqpVKmnjRqmvjq@I1DUQDlIbSCH4ATjVcqaIzH5eoljsBC2xzK@x7yzklrZA0FCb4GlZ3bBQ0yRARQ3bGlHpll1DvXU2RQGYFCaGLzERtFz2rps/rZ1Vk7cXYTTWLseNmogO4Xg/RiA7U7csZDEMq1bEnR6vF4LVOql5uVaDq6FYsVlD4kZMTjHxfiCYPTOhaFXmc/dnYWBZIK6tRavRHBmyT1eDwgFOABPYo2tE2xqHpVgPSb8Xo8EYW48WgS@gKVaBTo0kIiuJRp1PY5Ex1A59LF8WXosYaHCkmY01AzVtdvmsPedBQOEPSooQXF0bHZHBtUBpqlDDdsb3j8sLCe0@L9No2Hg4YLO@YoC4dTLq0ljulZam6@128VLpTOwPGM1OcqKERBIrKbim5EU4qSkhn5cEiU7SeWi1XYsE1n7IZHEZYObmDq4HraG4Ow9CfDk8BV1lAyWz2HRTcfAHQWjN5ig4AD0QofzvYBtFsq/FCInh4eMRwDNW2PZoktkIs4g8x7XBohwUWPP@6Wyw9fq0FqZYrD0piQ1bWdkakASSCGRHO6tAJAqjIxUXxIvdpbY47Cdw@SJKXaMkEiHvQdg2jLxXVomHc4CMUH3RuiHJttqQ/yowPiUeVlMTLbqS2J5lycUQ9aCMgNSmI9KK2B8Eg57rCtehOIKsVA6Znz5JobqJWXrK3rer6V65R8P@QKIHYPCgk1ThvUV99L0cAzLgp5n3f5fP376dGjfd4vSo3dEfWssI/cGDjtcR84mOtEx6bdTbJ94CfLdgYWkMGP/@a8f@w4HtfgwbKq18UVYmsw7hvUn1vscq2N13KaTp@6eeuizsKPR67RN3gH0/fd/fzJ4dNnz09PKmopFChlXAwEZQ7DkwI0D@IP4rqcxeTNnIwtkL9aBAWG8Mijx1isFQFq@@7b6O5XDhzpFO4FdB/gOhHQ/4WuT9bAUQQsUkBcO4JT7sLxSkvfoPtKTSkIp1G4S1xFEsL2StPJ/cLrdOacM@R8rqCQ6c@cs@TM15DMaXJhlHI8EC4omQsTBpSnMMG6ksVwQgwFc4A9s@@P8x@DioFj2dBK91ERss1LHGfniztMt4Wa89gmWYsD4azVM0burc4F1I6hwkNLkQ3ieGiNUqiDSJspJgaiysTzoNzzCQSXy0EHFHDq4@xU@YwSMIY14tMXKT5EttkAEDvVsj/dvyoYphSNBsEIKuEGMSibNK92K6vBLKlLI18SRSlLbqr28myip5WzyfZ@PeUSETpMPjubfJzWv5CTDBdlbN5Ldc0yJreSWmTno0WtHggAlpjMkwzKYWx3nH5b4UPTUP6AMY09u8FcYLAshEQ3uFgjf0WIhbPMYuUOCL7QYpJbcBeKrno7QGj5SQAIasMVuz5PXlyzGrRFF6o77Ftend2ontPoYea98cheXKjClcPRyJi6kphKrrDd408@r6XrHII0MHC4ucBLa@KvcwKNFjQYXE4GJpwQ9yyPmmia@bMwv5oKSE1oZBLQBxg8gTILEhI5QtSvzetZXjqmB0qUiZi700GSmfEbtdM3PM@0OW/xMf/V5OaDsyKZCiV/X4z0lViahkNBZbTQD1Ass5PTR/vHxypwqBuL7uOwaQmqndHqgeawKtM@JcOZL7GP21H2McaJM0wFqhR0CxoiPjBvGZgbOgaQOoqCrjmKgWMcRzxb4EyDzBSRq06CQLisoeURjQJgMTMOeSJgpaX4P7d5H0jgWWJRliBKArlj90pAWyuujm3rtepCI0EKJQSJ8l4krWGrbMZIfG1qceKfkTXAGRvo/JA@B3mo1dgGSDcKLbPKW/ayllaK9cQmq9fLfB4OIqJ2TmvixPoqQ9CTD1qTgBQ4H4r@VWdhlZ2fAo2vYCyOnwY8Kwm@BWRH4@b0di2VN3U5HiCrvAEH7ikvIrlkFRhH0V97QCKElirMLzmYX9AQytZz6i4vrN6E7PgIBPnByYIYzyXbqDAtHvcx44BeGCPsBJfYM8d1rWaflpd1@hZfqhE01iVBGAHJp0w4uTJWDKIb1meoZ1gYszWFfKWeoAT5U0MDfSLMGTnE4uwKiUmk1JGK7PoaHWS2qTNiAxmX9HH63vi9U5CPjx1A9rFYohjWOUhoiElkFB1nkux3w@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@l@MXi8tgTtcXpsWwMIcWXsSl8lI0yLBa23VGq0FxZA6Ov6O2QcaUwXzYpeStoMJ9BccwLKDR6rWNybJBa474xmpnWsPgMD3@aYdWItWg2RF1uOX3LxQrdXyU1/ZUxs7RwISG9QrOf1jJKtqEjiu24EpiWSwGn5eGKsRVs9R4yja/UwvVwIT5RnVXEajmX@FupQfSgM8zfyxu1N0uxeg/5pPRbfQOa8pUtwtz4IY5P3sGrl5Zr0ms5Yc@XIuq1@kvd52uBPzIYHum7i7Ndq@@47ITe6wjUHQEV@Hs5T4dpaRm2QuPlYfMaMeRPcc4K1Oh3nX6@0E0Z8FpZ6uNRB0W/@L6vkAuElKbdIaR8DcixNfFdKdrPU6PzuwqINmiMcHlbyLimlV0mqcT0zOrcQd8A5/aW5@wgXaCYaoqPIa5IGGdlLo2p//0FWo9VpPVbj@GUNGpQ8DBCsQAGb8S17F8ktez61NrvJ5Rugd2@KxOhwj3vm9Be0ftWkTI9rX1gDC2dfn8R1emPzbG5tK9x1PzSxH1@a/oZ749UWmRjUwzm4/wBLkoPQr0RncP3whqbarStFSYG9NrNu7WZeaE2BAV8iL3nZ2B4hobbMbr2eDhXqnMdNPt4Pcl6Q79KO@057NDnQ@VQ4Q5laU5Fd036re008U4erg@pZNPptNBhQpMyc5Z1nalMEPdLi7/nEiaXWcqzsDgRNwoZl6dBZAmvQFopgvRVfXsKXCymbMs2vSm@31OaNh2n/yElBUK1baE2BsolrbRbV2K31B2xhpzNRi9cHPNodlaNW/DWRnQvgT7Yb15X6OG5pvcqTQXnRaEKdhes60dwQjNXd6WC@y1xWIivveuv1iXFgIimFtTttbWOa6hO0@wb/DPJZ9fBK6qZtfDmhYaYz8X5Xz7rO5utjywIpeEUiGW1oaPSMwcmWdco@kb7y7Hrf1YGmjj4W@U9Mc1WarJvtlYFGFogF2x8z00zh5Qlz7Ghi@UZo66JXZU@LiQTrqsksD@duJTIhwOja/JN5Osk5WzMAhfc8J7dzLh89KLEF9m0INpshHk1S0ClOjenrv9dCvDJtAXlOh7cPeK2UPlbOAz6HrV91Qq2202s3XN6ds/s8WWjgW1V5QB@9Pim/3WoA9bdXouRaAqvcA3Ts@/0@@9DTxSNXFA6TmcpTvu47Q03bnwQ3KnRBA/xuXP8zvC47EDDylrTM8fQLrmO5wxNhWyrgvZxrIe/V8lQf/b7Fx1EWtvVB4r4318U/p19y67heMMhfRrD/tilF0VVaLfiXXpTh69eQbIzZ9RV3ziDpiocVbG0hSbdl4uYpuW1erhLlHO22XWarZ51F9JN0/Bs6zzlj/pw63v1XZEyFlMeobPat4C8o6mK/FIJ@5/g53BVoYsBJN6sBYY1@sqyQTrakKkMjfOWywdE0cRKOCYcqo1822aJ9ruWXo8tbwY0tNwpGOHlMxNoWIW7WJaxUrOiJdIzMSyWa6zkUlLSUSFXzDQoPNrK8aW5pXChKpbJ8NcqhMK5JIxCC14@hNxieRANEFqhoVtwn@OvuXVNSxs5uzfuurcFJh@xb4OKhq@lInC3i2e94CY8h7l955IWndEW59lOvtB4NrRmhi0@qwpA76dw9xN8G6CNjc21Ey65tTMuFE7rK4ZjwacBHyjU8crRtb41dPmbKZ2V83RiIRT00hcnEznVpsu72aLI2maHz4@g6S7lceDQDC5oJ0oLZ/txeB3FPFfJuEiznS6Ie6XPZoH9sKsUmqUrk5YzRtCaKl88NbsGLtR@bHm40nMJvxAzL1vRdCfsr48N1/r6GHK2ig1xFzefoxyF9/yibQm8J0bXan06VxABkoLAYpko/8xVDHS6XRaXPcvF1VWBYc2QFbIcZ2Lkugb0KJaEXBzUDzawz2o93x@1NPSygXdnOMVtJFMyrRtztzwafxXfVZ3KVevO1iJxOR4Mx674LMeB1m@Fx6cH5@TuXloAXHkNQpf1jL63fAw7NBgL@ploLmfGVXr6N62@02XfLKQZqHOgnqHavoRxHkLD/QwXDY3sJZxIab/nnCgOgShc9rmvoWzNDFMs2/LWj/N4Hi4g8r@YGd6m4PaG1GN8qw8@FIJyupwij@/uBcz2LN7R8gPnnTjjUctEY3AQQbjDIFI19/yly6LVsM3LcP9t7bwONJSOPfaU0dhe2yrk17YKJTYp5ENswGJf33/yPB7mBlrqfZd@akK3cOz2pzPTytUEC0xm2aCirZaj86H9XsYjfmTKMa0zviPOLp7r0iJx/chZ1hN6Nh2Z3nt3pUD4jwePzBbOKd6Z9lPniWM70BoNQVAOjk2@GXhuFcjyiBjtMW53Bfq070zmhMCuaIS4tmEMzSaUb39mep@2iAN@ZHjGiqaIRg2pZxiY7uQVq980R1/ScGDIvKqzO4/Qp@aEeh2rGYbXQcVrtbiyjCN1c3Vkbi7HHTqOzd8kbdPw0Z6slyrQFNDr/WfRVVzFPzdisLTnNp/Vowu@hMRs893qq/I6MptOn7/XLFiyLb5gwBhZppt6jJufyS2fZQpoX@5aGbK9VobMOk2gyV4YLs3gL@@EzEBqkw9YH9QzRi0H58iEYc3SndCO5TvEdLAxgK8qaALhJyCxjNZYHJt2F1r9QXNAr5VdiVBpHptN3FLUpG3@njG5XZh8zEjscQ4t9wp2BvviCit1nsWeQT8lfnezNdfDmqeqNaQXSeqVE@m0kkexLbP1xsDxNIfoNRu1nvOHPKeeknHFKHaoGtH4csqgLbBLa9L8ujZQaPqm4vVGJii/3rqBb//8hSUzJeOBidPP8/MzK1VXx@1RZp3lM@2BcB2Zijj2C2RJcAQY1w@V3ZWaJ4KH/6OHX0tBI9zIZ/0zCUB03T23D8iPR7b4vA8HPnNcr2NNjgBv3JGwSpxgtnIQBT68ZqBpa1UmoPTscZ@PS3RDi7IGbeqOKXT0pKL0SVx7pmLaFwqdEDW5nSOH7xhL7eI5hp7ZVsQGaZyDUB77m8eCYOK7ZGo1LBtxJaiW4oSd5LNibegy4l76kgH0LcdThi59U0P32eHjo1N16GrLe/093KlxS4@b23GtF9KhwaovjVFoJpSvVWtbrpd6eKIpe48PVQywgt58rkOBD87ZzX1WjoiKUwONlLGyF4S@prdcQfz09MnjxGx/J4vt9UbOwIyHvfdOTpK46@VrJ0u9w7EPoHZ0nMnK6If7mhZfwr7PbZo3XCU9l6S0CtKpCb1RYMZP@YENdypXLWdotk@nQ/NzaDxRgrvvmXx@ZSafGhdWF2shK64kFFVUVlTz2Xho2TZ0ts1R8F1VnufWEKVliz4p/lm5UAU1h0xqlFmuPaxbC7CoxbC0WKPwYZG09G1u9SwFaka3h6aU4f59EdM0bRWdT4wOlCvLrSys@QDLZo77zsV7TDKbovOiBE6KB1ylWHcuMt9WBiC6U/jCgXvhCMbmygUy6wAEzvmlFf7StKeGrdAs1zr1ogSxcbnb2iDfNN9jqipY@3OBZ7kunf0L1tuzWIuM8TsSPh2FouztPTy8K8KxoOX6UJ88fc6eGW7L6N8RMIyx@R4YzzSjLxUct8KjsVZOtLZHAEpfC687XF6fS@zEGLUde7q2SPiek@OxHT6r0E2KHel8qxjfvOOq/oGSsZiRSMTj88cVh7cq8U06Bh5YTftrIOz1NdsQ22jAI9hZJDbv4BHQ0HKbuOVN8kHU2OaV2OpSKmk3uN1HLslMbEUKDgHjB1lVNmN4BA@gioe1s01/jwyjA1jZNaPWG8SFlkuDTU2FNy2WxeYhVoIknx0@2z853T19flJL12/kuNgix9EyDEjI3zz5caYtQ24EIaBR5Sfa0Sa7PiRHh8Niq@/6WWKQqYVcVeZyNcuPfB/jbF4ZRipFe8VSyg3gp8g8NfKFKo5OHLafY6K42OpX4lus@kRNeZODlilNKIUSSy9LeGi4LmRL@C8eT02@LJNBX56wOIQMmKzrOG2Romuyux8/xYPdw8fPj/eZj@CMDS6ttterFHP8jDqsOYoJ5dSxaNq5wqIiShTKqlKJHkSBMFE1ykq0Q4/OhwPOhWA@dXBvn4i9xWKbBB8oGA0KJfVfvpW6iaq4gioOYaM@UlEmKI8B2Cnuuvmz323z81P9XfP@GeyjAWmstKdZEjvqVuynQ4pSVRuuPomdziulrXPBQamz0@0lOjkXuPISFZnFw1DidD4BP1ZfnFXjJ0QM4p@5iB1uPHcGegsXFu6b4zh08BiYeVbG2TuGe41VtovHzAPPA@sjEoD62Pb4UQtiO3cE@EgNRESSbRKy/LBfORQwurMBrNw0u5bNXBu0GNMrsS@Bz7BTW@KbNxWlGr0VxQfN7xdQet6gHwp469wYN3Xmpd796vdS3TID8yT9EGy/LGwdMP8KN79MYVnfPltmln4YCRNrHceaJx7QHOkdOlHf5ptkZ8TCI3B82cesARTNBVEag/MU@FuxmTyDE6t9DgUFLAalJDbH8vTMUT3W87xhKZVCNsIJApUWBJoTPjuvApOnXo/x0HDHdlP5XD6rpQBJ5cIHSKdEdnHnEQcYj5eA8aULa1h51QT22tlhMjaKZiVf5qWZ2jReZuRXAaKbEFa67CFyNQZxIMosBvhVRTRoIBJaHKOiPIpqURRFbQdaDvLHFgbttiCEzGJALE4jE48dnODVCt5oigMn434bzy@yndAJwpsCkKJB80OmuCyJ/ZxPHQ9YZm4nK9/PiatTeCuFc7kuvzqEzjlHHlRv16bZNiT/qGJRv1Ss9xxUJr3Y4IXLVn6BIE4QRElexrK1l@zMO7PrKc6bDNj0x4Jlw8xsg/mfpboreJbne/f2qVaxxTOpkFjswYnt4FjkAWSGxfSUnklp@fgsS9ns0iyJHIlkIDu4Q/8akgPRBGKiZVpfOkN3d2//8GtHz05undxEIaOLwUCSV3cSZ4qarNUDQzScrfkieXiQOnny8MAviBnS@ZAEBn1E5ERbl5OZUo8gZ8tHF7O2DMPF3K3G@AXfY7aIb0ZfhxpFuoWHlv6AdGkJl3JAC7EXE9cLy6iVy61DaQYvFQK9x3fR3EI1Fr@6qdV3qmd2JHqbE5ZUhJcRdQsrAZjO3K3NFDL77cxhxoIrfk7xcgI3XBczy@uivJnBY0dwH5/nnM8OXBEOIY9Qfv1kQERKasoPurL2HXE9enbAj86vIOIHlISPZQghnE@vo3gI1Kl/mxFKkdnxZOJkrp7h9vpWU/KPw@AndPkHCQWHc/GjLGJxSRxgyxOOifuNJqWJSrOysThKO4KVZOsO@/LhxSWo0KivPRtDT/KZM@QHGtLo@yPTNx07IH4fjfk0nsm@Nh5AuA59jk0aCQHJrUBkoGQ0QJXrTyAlxFlfkwSepgbp1fDEL5FxddDOxSZxtWdO2lYXZHssngSJ9rGm1VlwHhhmms7/sqMyldmsFNZWxU9wb1SY7B90KNxkhoBRM1TLbpuTWPQyGi/VIX10j16@uIjG5WW8RIfTidPa2oun1AXob2vrJYnhidrpHwG3TFoUi7elBLgtAuaHsvinqReLas@V6D6MCuriJ97oMRhBjYh1BsaQxcY2P7hGZWSNncXsJJ30oVT5KVY2SySoiwQf8lAZxeyQibffMcOesliqAkyArq7dxs8ba8hqmqrWwUyJxNkm3nKwBxoXHgIRl6CfClFKBLaCLAQdB8CIVxKVMzjEQX8Jz@YY0fE/S7zp0HcaS3SQJpRrVr3HQvdUzGuOcrFYEgU6LxWLDLjvtjhUUwD2lpzzdXmgrthkDjSDDq0qRWaC/LbEi1C6EY7Ip2J3OqATCZ08529aZwBrdi5cqzfCX2zfhrqC52yUnp8eNArxlMyCXe7dkdXGAQ06NS4SdNrEUdZQTVNzQaNl3kf7BKPh8UUNvo0eT9c5oAojL4jUSJgMi7e2zXhT09ZyvYgoSgFCZrEBEFsBGj44PKfLn1pa4rdc2P/853gvnBzbvJ/PNPoXiWguXYaXVs6xHPt480xRNmt6Ll15sFk3DO9MZkYqu/Xowux1mofd1JksswzLplJbev71@VDLb72sqa8ndblWqCTP68/O2bNnX7xtvI3Lk4upfBZj2xG2d3Qta5CBSGmbFRn@lj50YdPSZ1UXXY4CUBaJnJ3hfW/ytpxK1aJ1@CffV/DwcLWqWlXv19@@jde2IU@T6VkEr1FiRw/m4cV0PX5iWVaKnQ3ddht@To/V@UWAEf4kEjGFCQelxt3YYNIht8mu2e2O940pd7ciY/wceCLuk2@@ePECDS/oYW@ORXwOnflplBpGLsL0tP5nP924SV49a@z82bcHKXMDP0f4@d7NEzSfaLmPNzY@fvgwm00Clbj52TeffWN3dzf7KJl7VsvdzyrpjZ0//ZONDV3f0VMbddfV6tHa@fkXsp7Oyuqf/STaePbs666LxYJPhmlgxHcBfhrqVOfsDTznHYb/ZH7TDpkNNDc7b5geeRMBto5M6a8RYbwWVkhLCj8bTKve3/6vPzh6HfEiVT31YgRfL/I6ki9EuBEMYMv4totINbKDwfI3kWmqUqmAcfu//juIX/0awEGf6Q68qjkfVn4aqSoVinIdqebBoOk6pPt/f@tbKwd8HtTgkbPbuny/Ds8WPTsSHiqkpFOphdBa4Z52jzHb63mmgx@Lf2z4MKNsQ3f7uJZIJOqqAo/aoEgpTdPPaKQmzFM00BIJnMuMu7CQ24xBhAv4vYgQMwE3EUNxs3AgHuMOLxbDvVjylF/84zzHUiS/8cB8VK2C5NOr@lY1Qc/GWalENG@k2HZBdpwHOIAVPZOj7BV7LEhcldMFXU4mkw8aeKkmmyAllUlkRjbGKcMic/SMsJmNhZ0izI/GZmE@NNw@Pn/@v//5D//8B/T3Q/r9Rzx1yW5bndRWLbYVr180qvxh1apcHclXZ2R5wNKlQqmQIl@QS/VjpqU/uY7mMtETbBP8xx/QjARPtYovHw20VSPcpcpNMzfhUw0sFGIWZXk4JgSRT9QItLhiCYpSu6izqp@hZU/tARSTrG8X5XpVz@lHUHSaTAVXZL1NlzkRP0fsPjwb8Ef/GxsoDwIXfG/gQ@/7POiSZyPA5u5nEVUpUovUUmYdG4kg0ION0kahlC/pqQZbDai8CnrkIixH1G21oOogORRW2zjmDF9nCf85S9z5PFfVhjCSwcGfojiTiBT5R3iqEotcwVN/u1V7u9Xwk66JyprYUerVhMAIPmrjQT2h3NzU1JeJcln871QDY5meRJmhEXJSv1GUnZcArDYPNpp1onnnAULnwOmtNl7uAPjETm2n4uzRT6XqotRfVms78yAEcg8eJFDMPgAA1c06iycSm4qyUVuZBwBYjzHoCUAB3uzcVG9qOzc3Ozvwv0PvG/EF15udW//0mT0rwsz868hoZ7VU9Sx1JtimDnY1VUUXNXUGhip8IRy0QFLkLTQr7Al/2BPbhn/4CQf42vigySZPbifDEz@QcOYuUmSLMbOkbemZVG7ycX4fFKpaXcF@T0WpaflcnVQaKXKNGgDU2KIUSWE/oci7C0VyKYLml9piW5Eh07YzkS0QDy7b4P5SBPIJAK6oflXpzevaq3df/a/4O3v31e@z5mv8e/wG/157@Hfawr/j1/jHTt/g37GHf0@a@PfMxb/T1/i328S/0wH@PXyNf088/HvexT8pUgGNdvN@up@@SGvn2jkYLJYesXQv3dPaKFLTJktP01OWHjhaG0wm/KXBZKU7LN1laTttaxp4gsFjaQ9NHfh04a8DUEbwZ6XTCDx9wSCVPgpquoiAvtfQxMfPpBqLvjJB81Q1Na3mrUYdj3gGlbQcSZ2dpXjnmunZMp70fHPTaOw/fdRopGiO5uyJczT7PzoahK1r/wdHzpMjZ@DA/9HR0ZMz0FaqiQcJ5QE8lWpiR3zuR6rl@2clBauBX@MiqZ37Z9WMguZ8AiqRjm6JD3xmEOFb3TiTouwSmv/LMqkW5cuL8mWZDIH1RbkBZj@ACMYN4FgWKgm4QLyzFynSJi7huSC4ZEPjJXj6Jm5Ivbg8Q@0auk3BP9AjbP0H@Lf@v/X/5DmL1epx6MJc3ezE6InjXzx@dXN1I97VeCwmLLEd@EMHsGOUq5sqGinQFZhqsXg9fnPD3eAdi@9wgFVMY6dKkWcBod5HgjQpXf6K/cN@MW3xnOHpw6H57rOzSTodLzf9005xrse4pmnHeJluodhs1rT6n/6EzrS9H6dAuWy5rG0xbtGzermc9W3bhXK54Fs2Y7Hi7aeavq/lQWXIZuPxchks932wabAGYAsA1rfkAKrpGi2q/eVIHDPBJUIsTedA4@UAUbkk37sXExeK3d@N37unF9PX14HLcAhO2pxTo9G2Ro0Gumeur@WGTFPOxRzY04Xra5BP0bgzij3FOyUgoZiisY/1KqVZdEaQ923wZlpKn2HRM1zD80axN9YwKePKSVeO05Hv6bQzOov@7Pvf/vZZtFKRFZlcsxoCwFRYbmcnn61W81kw5wtAHHnzit9@0E0UtfjNZkrmBGDyZjQivLTCdpwLxSj6s8gOu1@FOu3iw65uIlTSLJuLx5pTM34FLr6bVixyR5bNxwqJovirbMRZFRos/oedu0wiu7W99QB7d5MVDwri8pVZ0W4qV2YJB8duyi1xUw/uVzLv3csUgaCFdPlMajQe7Z7uNhoVGdpGmdo8dCSRLuElIsNRtEbjR7livYaZq59Fo6XyA2IGrZBjkWhZhFOi0DawQpFoIFkd3IwIGUeYq3/PHu/u7Z8m9R1owPWD3b2kfvL8YURDa25mJ@8M2o/3dx8dPYcIzx7v757sf3L4@f7zZ@DussvZ48tX8Z59w6Yl9kv2Qvpy9MYwTcMcm2bjcjy@fM2@tKyGBWTsjy3Lcroj5poN0zSHEMx/yvBrWa7x5ZfGaEgPe/fj77778X/77re//@63v/vut3/4s69@@F34/S78vs@/3/@3xRy@f/bV//Q7737rt8HxP8Lvj@D305999evf4j@y/zH8/nPI7Y/FLxSO/ySA9cs/@@oHP/nZV7/yI/j9K/H70e3fr/50@e@H31n9w3g/@J31Yb7/7@D3exyWH/b7v8Xd8Hsr/G/xcL/yo3e/9u/5/5@KPzT@9rtf@2N8Ccs//9Gf/ud33/4Pul7403/z7rvff/edH7z7zrfffed7777zT/V3v/5vtHT49TvvfvgHf/WHv/dXf/g/0v/v0vv33uf/3Y/@@V/8b3/xf/zFH4rfT@H378H007/4D8Czf/sHP8b/H/zB3/7Rj/H/f/nXf/sH//Jvf/l/JsNvcMP/86/@LX//9a/@p7/5ze/91U@/9Tf/8qd/8xt/8Ff/56/8X7/@n/76v/v9v/4fvo2Ov/HTv/qjX/7Lb3/3L7/zL/7y21@teH937fur93D/6h/B5f3xfB8475OvD3X56hfC5@9DjVkqwCfA4P/s3a//EvD4r3Hbfw82@A@8vhdY5ny45XszC0D4zYVIEbM03zAU9EJiCxTmrWKRhv58vx2K9rOv/sVPAvi/NA9yzg@S@x5Wyjm/72F1fvfjb737yT999@PfePfjX0bBrWSLyd2koq1fggY9KiX3HuEwYP59wmFASP6LL@A1SdBwmpJAG/tCBPjiiy@kyXUKujTpB9fg@gU58YdxL/Bjwsv3E@64eDEchhvTvnETna/DSYNZE0PCG5JOX3xJWgK/iQ0wAb5bUi4DNkIdfbb83CSknOZ7RAQs7jmhof8J/EvZIotApMkkMYE@EBgSE5YAr4cJVqlUKHJlQkHBinEmrFqA4BMcsakgdIjE4yQbBQQxeUhQIGYlccwaW5UJj5hAeFWCQMih07Gs6XKiUHkECVYmjxjCQuAE9tWrSrVQmVQR3FtCARJKPCScEFglMam@BXuFYEI8KfLoLaBSqCQS1QImiJnktEo2KE0tR5mjvCcY5RvdGa3JvP@AsY9lrSAWTm4gwXhofCdmoe/TxMh98D9LbIns0L9vpN8WEXyDkhKp8GLBxDZ4fBEA4CqKqqoMfoqC2DwA7wkHlaBk4ZNIiGIFePj4IMEBChjLIkHlmyALpB@pbH3wk6iyD3j4uGYhLzcS2lQHrVTOb@PA5j@59fw3/2TZs9wVH4nTdHNzU4pU5Yx8RHMECeiqjs5L/OT/a945KDE5X5TR2aRFw5zG5uYz6m5vPdqCtwb/@xu0ljfBykSczSiO8EQZzzX7OMF/Dx5ssY@hDOg7c5OYksg4WRyoRXLvJBKyDqlWnYT0EiShBJWIAF1L6qRCMxMJKZlkTK1E0I8dHR0J1MjhZUVKQB3UMxracVB5PB5HIIaqJlWgKf@q9CUHVRhU8hVfdRNLnm4TY7qeLYOSX2boxMI6uQadNXR8@/YtsAzN55cOoU/FxNS@ni2QJzjwLWD9/tRfRK5nixLvQzItz2/QjNElXHEWl1iMbcUlvvKTIxHMFEb1QiGKpjiUiRrb8ld65DXptKSjWJL2S2lk28Tho@PDkxLjaAkixQJI8TKNwwlsipoUGQ5f7ETEhLSM5@w78gm@SzMUYnoRJGI8UpUiLRP1Zf8pS0/c7kNnAv3JpCwntTzOtcZpqI5J33BKpcpbLbstwZfsY4bHvvA9YlBLcQGvurPDiMTVK4WGL9EIJM5L1apY2ME0qXqyfwoRTo@YpqdVBr3Nq@y2ns1lc3omn89t61o2X8zmc4UMtAr5dE7XtWI2WywUt28Ye6WyksKviNMK@biKEycNp9PAs6BU9kqqfsEmKmZGuZGq/UrftLtebxPXW8hnaTlEr81aOol/eiYDb0gyqeW26xsb/SsFc3BGJXeFC2cgVelKgYrBPoKHSR9J7CNwggfSwNUwTCxFOjwqi/UguF07xheFyFoO6l9cOgNEOThpGH7Kc7YhsPvV1VXoJ0U2vvlNj1Wr0DNUDg@kCMi2HvMXSChWW@2pdA92ezwyybfLWNv63MKrGlT/0no9k1alyM3NTQcgHR7gdBpZeYw2vm9a5NIE883EkP7/5x/02eEHmlRxzbtjtCvBvfFQIeNX7UrbadEFLuVOpVan@3jKbbXptKeq602BtUVBVqLNvtM6j/qeFt51h/u9KikjpTYawAme02hUKtFUKnpf386VNlKjlErnN7FYB@rzfT2/DY5nNneNdcAlhy4v552KpbbqI/UE2Bbi6SU9n7vZEaeaVSFPiFoVEbkS@JVsxzZvcLV6yeiAuLxq8SVJJVnPFeRyrTyzb@flcv3mwcBsWwY7S@MK5aulEfN5@cYPB0mbUOFoA0xsgLeI4D6HUvosHV8ROQ2RAWXCVNoRB6lUaYlNDeRKHa9ErtV3/CNWqhKTdF3RM0pGU7QM/t9h0PH//cPr8K/jG2JldOkUj895CsUN8tNmj/GsV89hp45D1/o8NFsrQuz1DFpLtDdyXPfvEeahYZ9zr0cWP9sj8PrUwPO83YHl9VaEeD4c4NYrc/SPBmF/0AQEkQd5gIfwGvUdZ1mAbfb82YpcPglO0wJi8OO0IPjx4Sefnoa@p/u7e59Kefbw6OmjhU9OBMqxx/sHp4F1m/v6UXMBiG/sP368aBWfCLa0OHC3wXLbvkGTcDHiPehv3BPGXH5mTKPxBd8nY7nB4ji@IaoknfqbZ6h@WE2TtfhuuIk04Ru6hQaibRclachs55Jtp1nb6fcNvNKsswGOPQM3BZjYovfp5j1M@tIZ9dtQxcwN6QnuPyhqeG8TIiF9CkAG4xbtnrQ8CY8HaeNlYzhK3MSbj8d4od8KR/igExpHVrfnMe/S8QNITcNg8PvQB@Kb4cdb7@DxNMjtlk//dnApIhmeESmUgWG9m3LbHmv37mn3no2AwauFdKl0lr4BDqs8PC8NzYnnmkN3f1LMAr@xMXsONcAYtWRZL6G0TKSwE8s2//o3fxc0R5aT5by2dcCySdZQGxFjC4uha1VT0BQcswIUNo4DZ7JjS0LG3UqBjIposoxrITc0SSXtTy8WcoViRi8kC8VCNqflc7mkpidBv90ugn6T1gpavpAraslCtpjJgj4FvrnithThK09SWwQSviUAa7fwfqEdUiDVHmiKfK6AvYkZcRYxAvuYySbEkfFuWGhhcLPVllWR9SyD/jyo7wDRYC0WOTjYSx8cyPJDtOCs515alttoyRXS6e2HsmySzx7ofLosOzxOATdjyx63pNMP92R5zAHgOWay3EPLfh5HCWTZQsve7sEBptNBi47xIdg59@GWvm/ZhmA2WjIZGmaQ5dcBOAi3yxPKEqb7aME00eeA@@yBnyx/4uOTTgOEYx6OQ/jUz@vuriwfcsvuLvrsUcZzHNXP0LJLjyyPwAKVQpa7YOhiUyfLTTBi1ZDlFphaUwPc8DYnPOzK9gxZnnICIYlkeUKhjda5LDd8d0zm008/NXpe2@zyZzriX2DJQ/CxJuP9g@YnnzS73eZourv/yTH67O19anSm41Gz2xTRmg14HIgDPueD6eIDOB42GkZ/qc9n4GMv@DSmDRNxaxivASfxdDGRQWMPfPbAZ9lMC4cGzwCCNvF5OIDvQ6NJPv5DPvSdNJtyGRkV96vTlYxQZ@h2xOTAaI2cMtonlQ3GorFoclrLp@tl8mADUM/S5Ru6izFGl1ljdxMUqatpbVJJ1yuTyrbOp@Y7MflsoucsObkxuK8VQfcy7mt6NjEp4aZLpxNlUUW7H9Pubb2JPQUdK5MtyWf37ytyTavf17VCKb/9cmssy/ESvu9ntktvoC8WhZ4gvuK17fp9UOhmUba3E0ZKL21vx8s3QA4Pms7m2DMbjVjs0jTO43FEF3skkAV@E@SU8mmVO7FJclLhWLFpvDypaGV@DgtL34LVxkO/xi3PGXGIXQA3uZ8u0V2TslYsyJB@KhWLx0EykRCB72wJy4uvn56fnn4BMgs6g6Kn9IxfYFYW1k8@3VOh8yRseFiXeoD6sTNS91CwzPnws6R8p1OQteqn0P6Bruq74TL4kdNX9yfQwUUl2/fwj2BRxcEZ6umnc3BOoJvIU8ZdhGXaVm63TIZnmVltZlSqYDLaLEZYMSN@SS1vo1qtNCoDfl1kNYj1Gb85ewbm0OW4B3sbKfoVLg0XHo1K@mYW/ul4wB7yQHT9rR@tUXkITXm6bOMZniZaN9kkMpGqbTzm7GHl4dW4hIMYN2WzYuK1mnIEdx7ftytj2zU65jNzhFt5D482WYeZr1q4qPzVGV3AuYda@I1SHTF7Do@YoVSb8XmnkBUJF/s66B@cIle0vwGnNm@gPxN7GS@/Bttok8Xa6sP4/WwZSPiQNVgc3NKvOq86TGf5bJluJWIxBAa1jIhHd1vGK9XPADYHfV4qAS6CCc4BLKa1Cb0Bq00@Rnxo3ZS7lRqGvsbXjiLLdUWpXdelqqK8kKpQbcvTiFFxx006CJOlm5qezpcn4KZtZ8s91qw0X07Ko8oQ@tSs3IeSFwMJfOeGUQb6AaUAzptrFnv3S9@K7yi5CncsE7DrPigQ0JpXJrNiylRqejaf1PNZHHfIZ@CnJfWMjguwk3q6mNQ1aKmhBYf48NsGexZ@EAYacl3D0YlYPyYzJifTk7SqJTVTS0LO06@s9qt48jwGWghRLZ70nH281BMckImAcckKXyOe0Lf6sbbDjB2F2BgkSZnyaSR7bGjBC@Ecm0afh48rLLMV62/GMNDm6Xi4X6uXSvuT4dfBK6a8vp9PbKcTb@LxcgzEZ7zimq@lalmqouAhKgw3gK3FoAtzx4NaegPyfaU0lBsocG9T29ZLtfFmTdEgg@nr7o5cletQYDdM6DkoT7iqM1NWZm4N1KbxdlymFfWypNIcOKWmxfTiqvX/cQkPqxYApaGQhUhcFjuT/Y1MsWh0W49G49Eyjp5uyGLEDQQgv2gXJHH0nnZfBvVKLslFHQPM5CjtVUmHNawbCfvJLFuUIlfSzdXNTng8@TM2nRoJxbfeY6yb2JRYitZHgV7INsikqFUaYd@t7HaPd8U92mx3T4qUGAutNJfYmThLIbXB2IcuykrsVF/y7xmugoRUJTpmp8bqtG7CtLCHxT7HXX33WRSyZYwGNV3P1Gv6NjSeIJD9oLqulTcTKRbBZZZqFcrNvQJMdxJgJNKwCF8@rwfL51loFo2WB0aqZ5IskxwTq15ihRyOTZqQ6bcRLjn2rvxRlRKe6B4zSlxM1Orxt0@t/lUho/COP4iumxsqF3@V8mev9ByUlO34DtD78aBJgPYtl8Phu0jq1dD9pl7IPDk8sh@NDkx/dD/bkKsRltYUXP9bLgnXHB/zl4sFXdbPkxH2IFKOsHMlqpVoZTMbnhRfbr8svHzy/Oj50YEUOdu43nBw6Jf5Jcre2l/7OgSMZrJRxs4qkUklWxbrXapVRdvR2X1oBhjemdzR8kr6usqZuEoeeR183v3Sj7KTnQLYdVBxS1AUuYRerWpbOotHhu@@@n3cZn61//nuYxZ1jSn7uz/5ib79d3/yr2khSfSm7NLQ4XYEQqJRy29Hrq6GV1c38HC/XKQe4Uhlt@Ng5uuWtMiMsUspw9jaTmT1B3Y5JcJq21o84ioRMXi@nYu418JLTxfAa@@I2@R8To5H9o@tnK492EEm0ZYxiekWI1Kk8OTVNWNgaVXb3a6lkymVYqW3Ctt5q@ywtzgq/VbZYK8qVZzO1HBnhj@yulWtVhEKi1YTqa0o03PgV7sp1xOMRmahE/jS3LK3zuYFydkGKxZtcDfdLVc4bbnQhduy6c/ccl2w@jZz60uXyTg3kEq12zSZtmOyXBVKfisF6JzF3/3Sr@t6/u/@5FevG9eNL6BpKBaLeU2P/Fz7@c8hwJq9wH6vjAahcdMuGoLeHFtxs6fago4kXvfaYTy837fD3hwDjcHq2tBPR5t0gWoQlUyDHzDTjlGwLdwqmCSlmo5/iJclKVA@SWkedVtJgsG28GxlqJLSlfQRekHLyiogLqWPZqAY3sre7zuthtsfj4Y0uh@jeFo9ye5BFEjhIzyNZ0Ncnk4yV9HKuMz4VlSOsktUI4WIDUzXxbN9oBWRPoIoj4Hh6cImNjRwNy6GtGwQ8ioGITzJo12DtOuQdp9HaJBrjHLPAyQZx45HskGxlj4CxYCoYIHCwKwdCFAGkfIREADyEBOArTrbYZk4u7ISifLs4KAbXIDK70wX2/MkjIbQ2rjz1I9cxnDgBAo93smAfCFKGPSzkKMPhMPgc4UV6BJgdLKhykVbdd8bFMCiYzFilDV2794Mq0rFascZ5Qjhn1tDHI2icrCX4wrA/M7Ux@2SnGR2IoGF/dE82wHFE4QucJ3Cz2Iqh6IyGa03kgT/7820yJELRUUeZcyAKC9eK1pAMoiMZOdl2GI7Fabp23EWIN8C3FuEFB0aFPQQzyYfq/oXvucNYPjziH@uqYS3pIdG@ATfLm4FZdDajfFQSTwQhAsDsYWTH/mBUuzQ82MHsSArVp9Cd6wR9F9ortI/PyiW0eIYbXbeEuFB60v1LMOFnrk4figWhmbwNfCkHJHOBg3LtxwoUHfo2HS0Dh0DgMtmgSNARokTSjjaY/sSDyEWZUORwxi5dDoJcj5iTEcF0b1OFBenHpsj6OT6tEkys6uy1qDN9CKLEaPRSSp2AC5OkQjhpomHWo2cZt8cAEonpsnwdBm3lEp1Qa8ZN@k4mScW8FXvwIKmxHZT4gqt1KV1bqVO8RBFxemABi0250ZQFcLqx2c5xdEtfcc5Z33r3OQDt7G5rc0u0/NJUFqTQNnZDwhbwjFiPZNkafBO8lDw24bPNjcWkqG4G7Fp/PY3o23EGlii19QmWSO8HuvCsEP0pedaEj1gd@r6hyPQFn@wq4HINcW26EoUd2QG@/0lccxDhU4YUHHwfhgDLc0/HgGNoIubFxBC0SRsY0BotvyNxliLIbcfUQNAdQ9qFp6U5I1KuD0eMBm1Yy2oekLA2@xjltElupaEzq4Q50wADCz6yjx08IOomA/Xa0PBqHzeGOQK1M5BG/xwf6ZgP4zvczea6RSrGXuzDQEOGx1Kq8J4tfAtuZAFawfyM2V9AzzzgOESTDZicgLAJuS4zEEH8Rejc26XSJaU2G1ISYYQBKkBCqkK/v15LHRasAQeDw2Xn5UnzlS6vLxU6XCv8chSTRdP0HXxUsDUsGuBNuykPHMwFHeVWHh7lYA7Myn84Gy8KvL@hC5pLN6b8q8kddyKWJIQi3bcKDaOF3hAbHdAh4LgaRwuMdSBRYdLt2I0oe0K/tPrySuf/0rIf0oheoNAGEMwk@Q02UoCsGSzdZ7sXLbLwuOCKiQAh1I0fUc8S2/kWwaub7KGnSCE49GKdd/e7J@3nL6DOonMR1ZnSfMc@iGnvlXYh9YEItnmJdsdjYxpjPzjGBoZODYltYdNodknHzBCM8Ou@Olu1qQ2rc9FnwTRoVEL5o9HeOKHdLUeKD/qD/0n3H8C/hPuP5kl6idbm9S5SoZON5gd5Ho8KMoPiWCmfpgbfizezIcgg2LNNA4CQ07n3G7g16pQbJ/e3AblWPEZA3hiCAQ3Y6nay7PaWd12zcuteiLVBWaXiRBQ4gC6VieaXrYDM1K/f9EfOu6ck43ng0GrJPBGp1ZPcAPnFcxjUEDEGJxeFh7p1B2ofBiIKwQiwwAB9TDwRNVg14tZ8XJwWCR5AuPU5BmNOWI1gUydtC/hJdxAXeKk54QNA6qHAKF7kCVAE3yYX3P4eem@dHgxwgtj/bAKHfE8wKNFovUoUHKhqnBZU6ZCCmGlKD6aQHZUVyuLWfH9oShqC16hbN6I8g@jv/HB6HegXizHnhiWNxhlKVxVzIkJarUpqgtRlVUroXIFDFJbRt8cQcu1z/VT0VpDMlspv5vB08EsuJd4PVwsVPitOC8f2jYk23IpYIVppQJZnFZ4teT1wicpJ3gQzRXRpj4jiPhcgACM9NJopog2CUebVCpccLDJimiXISQnhOSER@GhJyuQrIto0HsK7hXF4qmDdopLwmSAp/FmFNSgoczwjjico/4Sjz3CSUyR5kzmEBcIHkIVG/msVV@aei2EdEhoLQBARrwFoM2vXilJiwJPUwJbIKM4KX0ZxW2CDbisAAYjEVzmRwPGAiajPjAo/HKC2gGou3KiJskarjajvzT/yUnf0f9ptx3T8yG1ecd0cuHvH8WxjpQNVdCQ9qGlsyiQsSfzXNymO6dzRPCWsp4DWl3z0mGxJco2uKf8i3hTzb7TTA0MXBeCFzIE1/PG/f4DzoawB0PHMzwnmy3xTpNFbLcsfd5nsLq2A12T8JGgoOu1HdO1ox4Uasvp2pZrJvFCYK6ym7RKgZ8pLIX1ZGF0XEkSQ4@8G4ugOV@hqtto4BVRjUbMNfudeCk42BetKrJnNCph/xdMofggngTQo2HMwavOvfjdMPH0WhHt1Gqdx46GwjMKiewykGEt0P/BtwcaDHOdWc@RztFEVbrpxeiA554zcLqg9Y1dVcLYC@APZ7ARIWM4JFySzMAubSl0fDHVklgracRF1M8@OCr7TI8Z8SC@Pg9gjhhJNlqkMVJ2tCS5xsrkeDQ/vZMPx/ckjO/JenypF76IM@@aV7jnhyWdic0gQMAZGpm70cCsg9xq30JnDpXAGfUqHuG9UWzTuqs2YroLQXdFcLUD/JEMbC7YAsQ/X0X/9QXoR99/3@Iz8N68kynImwEuB4zRmeKuP7sZg@CH8bgUWZJcwNqP3jMtCIu3HhygCgFqLAkuG48AhIo5hG63GxxM7QO@g@dx@dQtvqc1VRXuuQSn0UWSneuri@hRo232janZjomQyRBcP8fH0GEjefV@GUdBR0LP4X29GLRd8cAXmnEkOg9UWsEyRvIiHl/NVjyIFXAPjZQThoer6Yf@t0QzDvFV@Gg19AOiUTyOyr6wcPhzOB1O@SmzfToK25ejvP3hJYk7pe8mCNBBrGNPzpKNrxOfx7EgS@/RIgRh1fks4yGQPkQ8X/F2GX4Yie7OKRRuKFLFL2Vp/sT05SVurSvxEFf4PMmnjd6PJe9iuvfmuRCrcWAzEbb3YU3ILci4IKPVioUhcpe1JebYt2QCutE4nb2iVWksEahBTJJ0nkXdbdIv4hL2jA/hiwNOn8MXAXZNr8EZys8bjmmJOxoY@QyMYUhrES6gpAOUEBU5yQUaoVCSb4bgVzdBmq2VabZupdmaSzOoAfNJhgJJrbkkRSlg8awrgr7Z8VZIZ/TCvjN81olteGzHGOFoxVXUipasJIteREsgkKNmtLQfA6EcbUdLj8jgRksnZDiPlj4Dw6xuRa@jJb9aYIARWMnwAN2FCEd7K1rai8VvJM84N10/XTVaCsoUwtznVqIIkALzDVojTrHZjsimNzKhYSOlMsmQY9wkdp9oHCZJvzT88zsQ6Cx19MQxzi0KzBJMm2s0Qi0GTweaDf@s3iU1uSRa8/2jA1rQFATBZBLQxwvHIfCghkei88KII4a@NKMBX0AQ5WZpOUYs1JK9JzoideBQKuT59Il6KukD7Rj51yBwfZYIXXwh4vvlNQ@CF@D74YmRV@F5Cx0/OcII52TjS9BCor6KrskUlvU8LqL0wyVEY93zgfDiST8ILyUCG5LpoMPR5BwmNnSG80xCvrgi3grHoUE5XimRexeikVQQNXOFNzmLnKFgCFf@@LrshOIhanMiCD1r6TqvZUG7QLIYvWayLqSp8soHKIRkDtRws3VOl4o8EkYKx8VNktqKVc2QH5cnSZJrXkxCZBWPfBkbHk896Lzu40EwH9Z99WNOcKwlhgBCMYNUuHx1PkB/d7j@7ivUPhEWElimWC9vSm@r12tb2QXM@7NkbxcgeibZo/hS5ShIYUZy6B2ENPN1vHZLxcclH1zJ54kG0Be0fZ9sQZ/gDrot9i04LNQSRhfzjuc6OJ7rqwl1WyPpX6i@0qJiSgIOz3iA6Sxr63HlGV9WxOhD49tG/4MLeDRfwOHCQ3iUgdECyXktH41tWuUyq9sgtrkLilStxLggp@nSoJhnjiDuaeo2mLYFh6PG8aOjp4@/AY3u9vZ2XLTR0xl@WGtxrDVoxzlkWjsdtAdLui16Eu8JwMluHI6nS143zmz5lizhwhqUAQNS8dlP1PG4kGUheb5QdyEeDxuiqIB1PqsGxpxUQlXHwCbbEnT1gCCmF9syBBBfvQV6J6m3FqcT8RsNvNiz0aDmq9HAxUuNhmjFsGj8GfH4zyMbqbE7ojtD@XUOl5JEO9XZoyP24tPdU3b66T47eL73GfvG0XP2YvfpKe53fvb84ePDPQa//acn@2w2ooAPXn2DHUqg6yOzZeKdY3heVpYR5D1nOOVyJ7YX5@4nxoB96rRMnKbacY3Bgx63qLbpVXmsfeiOTnEM06LrjQaWh@st6G4e6MaictOmHXe41J9B2Cb0aQfY5x04batjQVgJ@75Dy3T9jV@sb0EJgrz1N4cmuZKE1/DQ0iG6MAtXYF1CdAPC49wNgDH4@iu6O9VyeQSzrTJBuOD5YAqe7h8/OWG7Tx@xvaOnjw5PD4@enrCDo2OwPvvG4dNPgJ6HJ6fHhw@foxcFfHL06PDgcG@XHDgCaZXhnvYvx663FgUVgxNVWuc4801X5Aa2@VFv1ODZpUF7D10WHdsofSyjb70x29GyNHZRfcH9jjRVwGKbu8effA5tPjNf4wynPxVM6w/k5y5dB7WZZjuUGlSWKtS3sqiu0OwpWpzmIwZThqfDm2XanR4jc5L5wGkRT9symbyHa1Rw7JtvYqe67IOGhDYANoLyF6xUGN3qEI0mdwhkFVJr9R08Ho@nxhcRCgtGfeAvNSlLRDGxVgaB4laFQxvHg7Ry4AB8Dw66SNYb8QAsEzjwACzLHVAVPcS1IywnQoy9ozGKZ5bnDl8Ohgc0Lcy2A4eHBvViCwInXm5UpAYLbsXBLf19uruDj/LQnWKG27IsiuJSeLzXot/nFcPkNyqBTORTibS2DULKIGw6ONUglr3xywTRF7gB1wkZHc9lsUpcZae4OMi0LX5rSrdv2HwJ1GzpDvEeK@DpLhWxwNYKbhtp8zvuiQHxpqN5PIJ4j4RWaL5vPIj58FaKhlgjSTd@@UvQ7kLg4S0EfhEwAEiZ6@m0qKWiLaYIxukIVo65DnAkjtu@DYcHdm6PW@ZcBLFqK/al9eZNXBA5OddP8tcpEnZQRG/MEaiVNJXZcUZQx0ms0v0MKAVbPWfoWbwMY/M5oBknauYgNDZskNqrSnUuNaTDYoq2Y4cSbQIXr0i1CUz5PqkSx/O580B8zS7rA86HRpivu0N0jCZeETubO0viJNKlicMvoAjTXDkOfk49woTrn9JMdrxleN9XoVJ99PBMefsqiZd@cbHA79nzFx3iDxgT04LqQfN8tGBxhHqXqGn@ZS3uuImxxRo8IS2xlvvAoB/Ys6Bf96BRDvz4cuPb7rg/ZtGdHK@vKzyWgpJJXL3o9mIz6ZZkNT/JJMWpM7EEJCQ7AVmQ9THfJUkwA3n9AHfCYCmUgSI2yhHsty9chSJEiJ@75rgDkkXcSCeKO4AfZ1VaUTG7oBN3toTLI/Uy9rCSqMZTswUlLETOmC@ikz5kLR4PLUuh9uoWuEfrwYH8fn9whbXY8ebhg6A9Wgvtg3BTEqth8WYpBOv9wb5dA5Y3br8QWMh7cjVg3kjehhZwesCcyc1IsJp2fYqvbpUd1T0Ag20vjqAEQEOpjW2aovZPpo3xCPEwmJlCdHL6aP/4mMm8fwJxQe5hl6EtxCDC3mDPZqttLZuEnRooTUFnOVCefJe5FW3@s64yLyXeClEhdJCkoEcgLGZX0XasCZd6omUhFYJW35NA9Ck3j92VL4PcmgB8A31AQHZWaKEMSkuzGeGNj@WGF4ELuiW5bhxew08rrHnbjfe8jaZhQOE1QUYXd5YsL78XXD8u@elwBct8PaYMt0GThvYG@gkneCU8BFTV@RJcUyx@keIie65gR3za4cKv9LyG/fdnKGIkroRzXTgk1oVyLFDj@vGmr@bQgkRsBgxc6Sk8@Ypm8PBFPLnshAs0Pmv0YvNNECiZePPXgzBXQPT6TTm4hjo2aycrgUIermubhE3Nx7KOo7MCdnl1oI9xLXR@UTwsJgXSdm1Syj9MUryVmEvJp/nSzPieADmfy2Xugr2YCz@68veFzduQRfnpDYbQv5@BdKcuDe8D5x4@Tfr@MwZYQzq@tN6vMAsRQdVZ0qbM5Z0aozB@gAsfFwJk8JhovExtMdU4myzgthw6b5HC0CnIrTyEqnCQUV5rblH/Zn1yKJDvTG/jw9PjlQ0D4dLBG1yV/8QZueZsV17okJWQE25bnXczRyObgvH9TAOEEqNtTGs329FuO77glecKPWm@LZyTjtidxJfdJv2xBkqEhhdVvD8RR/fKi8N7ilYOZ/Xg8PE@26JD8DpzY5HySI6HZM@GZa9DgGQwjUtg80F7@D52S/ADHJI@SCAT7eaLEW3id@JGFAGtuUY3b4hloUK2aoul33Fbho0nfiTlj10mJ@9BRBqF3T86iC8bWU@X5@IDcu7QjkGspKyoMkUFNxzQRUjzIHhponuowcKdGv5KyTW3XhsprZDOFyXKnZ30koNasZ7calVkBo2vYQ/c8eiyfd51ehcd1mfDL5uT1vTNa8ZyWZaBtPR7/KRULV9J0emS2/AusGKaOFcgeJ/uIDuTGVPpZFOcWGazfnh5g8XJQJ3mEu6QWOBStjXwuRC32HmVQS1fr9iVdHlQs@tl3OTnJSpeQkvE0OEetKIgY/jMfM2rY5saHnU17QuGFzDSzVliawijrSHg8sQYWc7j3aefzI3GoQKAQ2BirTcNqPO7Ez/C1Wy490S1zcuYGCZLMuRYCRUk6SPaFaThbnUaT8bhmLYFmEGpJEGbdSf0nsalj9LqeOg55CMSUpC12LV1LX3kb2NK04gCBKlZdR@dHYIzCxPDiSHuOuWrqBWNq2sa7p2Mh0DUMCaJQ/lMlnFPISIq9nLV6pKrmkarh0jgZaHXFI3t7NDVocBqrkqjeLiUwxjRhol0HY04AQKfIc02YBKkubu07UOC7KNdQwN3oTEqj/bJ0AJ5iTRF9MHl3@yK9jdR/B0gACf8R1znUsUQp9C8QJHkewdpcAHPIZvv@OM0A26r5IXyEWYWYfP0KjPgtFKcaITJCjKB@0eXSE5OK3hEDhSNbLeyEYSP8@BEEpqnFjYXaUlFSl5V/PRn0WKhaIofzQ8cIsVHd1IDR7qge/TEhGo1ZXtmvw9Ic1p8NCMHGml/r0g/EaTv1jDNeoA891du@Stz/ir350jNQqnQwM8ClcKB5MjVLNwNk2fBkrfSqjBSXlQo6ZYKKsksbHldWFf1nIY1C1wNipJzZeCxM@ehhHxeLil97rMxFydg8MC/xv0Ff@ui5AMs58I@mE8fv5IoIJMWz4q1JgtcqtrW/1vc026lsWz5O/0UFTCRVqDBRGNEyEHEyBk/cgFjXGo4LTTYcxA4NCqcxFl35se8wMz/eYR5lfsO99c8xZ39UVVd3WDiWVnrHn9Id1fVrl279q6v/VH9dzxp6RRkswRQUwgujv1NbMdCKX0w5XACKzg85yexLRVDKKt5NeKQzCRK2z8lsnKR8S4VR4O9GOcEa4GMGFSiOleJcFNyWIR6KPm5AYJgIqMJJbklVXgmC88MsJjruaqWvSDnBByaFhfxIvpFfsV/StijyKl8ycWJzxjzKTeevZujBKJB93liMZmiowm6i/BH2ahvzCJh3bM4xMWDxJFxCqzr9NgHu4vH4M/1OGEOFGqkmKO7TpGUDjPkFfs@1oWY@GD9w1mx3ruwxh71vako4zbDJS8sK@LgjvFmA4zsRNFkgtvRqI9aR1rw3ZMLtQwRsraO6pYQojGzZ60aWvZw/jQ@SYd0KJQVxwj5Hg1EwoTgtoc3paNiB8M5wdCKJy7@JGuVBzM@0ACZebXGbuaeuA1Yawq7/Z6JBPccSw9SOhi5bS9rwRotgNWPxU3tsnzL83T0G8HgYjClbVnWX2799q@V96jPfZPPvcobJLuT6uBc9tXr0MEKiKQS1nKwjF3Pv7YsQzfcZt1wBgGmxQFO9B@BN707bzDwrDLMGJQxgEVr4I3vvE7WsuqeVgIjXGRl1EyiH/bwdtzmwx1YdLnAjOglHKRZHQYchr84P7O6uE26srSFSqtQ2wxdfed3kIDK46Q7RO0wKSwwTADTAwvdeBMgyootoiiR7lniQmuXGzyIAmpgnBNDN6HJMBhO/Db0DJ1kWX0AxWqQsLJBJ4YJ1Nfuu@gcnF2EALrHhBRQCChV0rdwsKTS/A/hIGTDlI7dVT3jwOg3JFkBcffGPoy@IYGpV6iYgTt0cHO/1hCN473mableFfD8oX78sbZb3RU7Z6TjRkU5BbQV@8cHMLpobTprzY/hQ6LcgJIJSrDKR2ei@ulDvdpoiOO6qB1@OKgBNABfLx81a9VGWtSOKgcnu6R9Bwji6LgpDmqHtSZkax6nqVZVzArLieM9cVitV/bhtbxTO6g1z6jGvVrzCCtDrX5ZfCjXm7XKyUG5Lj6c1D8cN6oCG2bt1hqVg3LtsLqbhfqhTlH9WD1qisZ@@eAg1tDj06NqXZCRgNHKnSpgWd6BLSzWRO3crdWrlSY2KHyqAPEAwYO0aHyoVmr4UP1UheaU62dpCbRR/csJZIJEsVs@LL@Hxlmp71AF@qVyUq8eItJAicbJTqNZa540q@L98fEu0bpRrX@sVaqNgrAOjhtEsJNGNS3wMjGqGmAAtSAdnndOGjWiW@2oCXPGyQe0d7Chk0@BMIBlGYruEoHRDAJbC0Q6rp8hVKQDdUBanO5X4XsdaUrUKiMV0KKi0jSzQYVAxKbZTHFUfX9Qe189qlQx@RjBnNYaVRs6rNbADDU0yDgD1oFKT6jV2E@AFz8Cs1qKc9PUnaK2J8q7H2uIucwNHNCoSW4hslX2Jc2zGCzXOETxh3hm4N6YByvd@U93HsaenD@RWXxGoyMmVY53qzAjy2BViTDhBGadzVgoJTMNZhqdCK@RkDUd7@q21/IH3SH6mOpifPBxE/TSeC2KjZdCXFjfuItEnq9QgWSy1fpYbsFGt9Fq2emnlIyg8b0S8hj8W7ls2UaMhY87bzz42dpium9HCFV6KRWdZKiHCgjMydR/yaZv7o1nC8fpeLIYOu8jYHV0FLDa5BpVKTA0krMjXl0RVkknE/TuS3aggikFPttu4TkpWkZSpmEA/wZfwxeeHIwPMDrzcZfj4CaW0PB/91Q1XAmFRKB/MiKB36Uqs4Hn/dpL5czqcM@f7Q2HnZRtqzKUdwL7wF7K/k7xK68XK56JlydkSe0sw@cHat9NSxitf5YkE7JfsmNqWQr/tSb0YytsOOYDnppSVXRYLQ8tUy@5OFokpYUMbYHuFdTJuOY7LH@qneJuLrf2uhD7vq@/s2yhvSDGqIUJ75zKXdLP/iVnAAGjWBxAEl9GyHAco4yyN9GZ7yHjNWai@wVorr72aF4HksBC9tbtm3XibDz2pyb2MA6/r5cPd0729mDoRGxfb66/2ShYOuzWpzT/nmE9FOSVoo6NYB6HdRolGVJSgYUPSYoRajtkf2Jgx8GMGFxddRp9xDgP2m4jasmEAxk2N8B7XAZoopfwkA4JQQE4nluKXxdKpmSAVKSpNrbmxp3SEt@FtRLxgDRm6c@o16b4D2Fr8VcirhskGUiyGIXWBc6F3QWNe4k9ZSpKmxsK3INZsgnFxxzGTdOAjrrIfha9a@lN8rbRiwGbMqK8UrdTSUDieRwLoewqBizZHyjOiDwApuhh8OWT5Dd4PJMB7ijcnRtMypMGkHFPl8Rz6vAwWjb6XEK@LBWhi16@1DVtCzzltyVSJHvyOFkHBjGkgVC5RKPCoogBLug4IvEqyQL2p2VbfGFOxeAdCKcgOVa@A@cuao6EUlDxQ@S7ikohGJYOcsJUu9d1WCrLmY5jocgZIdMP0YPg/4k0WQB/G3acAD2klhEE8EmUJKhMK9i@ElH8e6VoMLQbITXNT2chmAezY651w6T2Zsr@NUAC2Tsz9eGMwh52UwsIgEyOBxum/GqTtGsXtk4/JWxZHPUkg/bNKCXkXKGmijm4mY3LNC270kq3gi@2sPmsyajwAIqKn3jjdkVSD1um2FZevAgSDM5W8T@cFToA0QJPXHrNVqtxzspJKVPjgAy1ZEw4HR0xCZalD49q7VaEESIzMvZLzZciFIAuIT7z7aRbP4aCzXOjERf5pqwmRcHDaOC4TcbJR4asuyJDzL6HcF506DAELwaZ3OME0WfoFKovhCZSL8hQBCsJrQ7DOIM43NpZIC1Nq/caezqZRA7V2J8MOE69x6daKkeWA3xIDE13@aw4dGeAcv9pzWYWc1YawzTaLmJlfCwhy@MlKO3hcAxLRxfbDTim/ZmdFafy0MEbBLdjGb8Q5jN/LE8k1KIfqsFlE@/eaZrh8O2EWuBP0FuhkyX@oCbdeGghyuFJppkNkQLmVTxaUoeO/nQ1L1LbYco20ITCkhIRt8WG@PqVczFBZchQjyjoB3pzQTabVA/qHbT43Q/Hv@Lcj0ugQcfr6MikBkg6C@ROqg0oxmN7wk0fDQM60YCuwBMQTYk8H6RpQ1WYo99IdpJ2TYkwOibGLqWW/PF6NJMqaymoKGRcWTsw30YGOhOptCZDg@pgofm1dUJl0Ybr4dHNGEULjaqtReJioIeULV5EFF@opSM@8bipn87wSR7yF18EKD3wBXXccgmKCOOaFfWq8@Mc4Yc2Bae@N@6YZ6Kwkum4Izx@o63PcEC8qI4OZdi/tjsJvBnsANqOP3UIRiv18/B60KoM@27PH/ou7NMwhPuURzx8nNEjdlhvPLwP6H4fSugYmTqz8Jnjy3AYNnzXesmCEZormHijlGmmMBnPytccJoJOztEIUOj5ivh7FI@Rpsu8Xg8LWVH/U7LHy9uFR8u@yi8qzBp9BCAHuFLMgoJ9SCfkmGQ4nxbmMlx9K4OB45XICNd@xGIvgvFbIBGpYSIYK2TmzBLMRuDO7FGMzzvTdIdiEI4x0JK36@GNNEGKPqddvAEXRpF3aCmwJfKbOaMoa1GmGIcQH2aPk3vtzZ@MPSDwA@jnXy3ilkWMQENcV0VbCni/IqOMAi5kHujTGE0jMYxifg9moX4EaGsahxpNnj1GDbL8gUWRDLM3x5UokSnY@OCVcakWDDmtmY2TyrJYtiluBy5BypNU7nGG9b5nP0vCj0pcPjnDgakiIacMpB8jVRuohHd4xsxrTZQ5pvL3JWZt7am9FiNgcZHJmXGdbCqhVi7kgeLz/IpqreEYBuNEjHrS1GM5mAxHy0@k3qNjx8LIbIto3bbt7xoCM7MVYbJc6RBpizN8nBWsOD4xpolSjCzNgIdw@0rPms3jRJwWWyhvxdbsO3R4jGah3ZSeVHR/d1j2cVK8Q4teNdFokSLcMUhpQX8/b0HDW4@PIBImb69aNGK0cMhozfjRABUjk6bS0ylE3Cdxj9GjA5TDejtAO7N/HiVq3EhOhTxVSZEgl0hPDNyOTpswLo26aHyBYeJ4hasHKb3gnKZnpMrLZ64wyDAmMEBcFXuZ8ByKT3DDzorxEd0O0E210FoojyMRPJVMCwcd9F8TjKLyy8MdafHQmmXylwWGNNWQYFdBub4FSfmbw@t5a0pQ5kgBIr6AFLpFc2PT9dNb9aNtgXwAgUtTsrT0zaWxMbZYBWzgn5nUmuIaOKxKloxIVFQQWjQ0gCzALqXX93i7iqs/f8wcj9YNUoxgA8GfU/izKktgOO@NnKY2Fpl2ZpjFluRmabNFpsRFQobidyS/FEVe6tLGFQB4jDGUL@YBAoY1JexRKUChd0zOiyAq@wgKFvMolvCRoqKGdp4L0pGoMsPrdSNHblGOtyaMzEIgsLBYnCdEBNYsi7OEUGCiW4iLkePN4vaEOWBBrHifKQ5dIXslSkPdc0xAeCRs9YhynhfpnORgSny9bkcSNX9T6tuckZqLpwJ9NIbnmXw8dTMXSY1Uu7YWLRopCfSwzVojiUAK20RYjwo/9keuKWbIc20TamwyIqsMaZ89wK3UPe7bsv8aiG1yylZrDAXP9AxX268WX7ESCcr@7QDsQsb9L/x4Y5VhqkJEXhVAYemUr0uK94O0YE3gTI@two2uCrSn4xOoLe2wKz429/YiUV@vZsrO6MYbr@dyOeThKzP2vTKtxpMkf@hEczvd237fGd3/PP545dDQj3fd94PhltpAe9AjIBNBdjju8cUQiANkxdwZ6ceKW/3bbte8gQEVlNh30GucUwZDEDT/@Nrm5WOTzn8IpJxff8EGYvt@EVr47l1eZ0ooSgsFpdEi@C6hlGdAHvzQRfNsragiYDguK2MmmLbsYukLTiB4sQl1FkUvtr@E1smJfa/fH6bFKV4QjIECnj3EC@ztmQVynAUVjOTcextQONq08O78vuFWjFlMVkdwal5S10yosPAYGr/u9arTUSpx/jkBswo0eRWbuYrhqdMi0UvYMlb8E8AyHwLaT8p9445SbaJTPDPM9FKAwyfA6FU@vXDrE8li05GYpNn3cyNRF6ObpVgN0HSblgIqlD11L7XkkeyauImLab6LNMwxDIkThlx5Wgn0NPvzRsW7Sbf7tEGRbgHgjv2nD4ikAiAJlOIH9MQg2v@SAbHei8UT4fUN3tUxP@5ggRYWsKwX7eJv96lyuSyWRqurolzegYdMRpR3ymIXP@zsiF1438H3l8W19fUCj7m79hf4uKM@PogdgEEHnKvt6/EuvEJaEd3G0Fgbu3jJKS6lC0ut4napEDjn5R306oenv//7f/79P/7LKcuX/8GXHXo5/6wzZbNZZ6n9ZenlQwHfz3cvl5euzpdGl8u9AnLZPyho@LA2ybih9Wh2fGUleRYwvpIZqdpmU/AZWVSo6/xu3PGvMLpsiWQ7cJLya8AXR9EYm2x7xncP3SivYAev7hyI7@QBiSQAneFpPPRO20P7O5hvgJKAC5qBcnlWrahze4wGozNopUpSBuKhJeudhy4tYSAFdMWFGSvjDwJvgAfgd7Tk5eZZlgu//qQl@df5fBj0doZTsXKREis5sZIWK4kE/eQ33sJXe8nx0TmXs8FuIJFIQ0qoWUArQxH4tM6j7QNdtRMjt2Ut0Y09CElFqaDM7ASX1ps/8pXh@9aCnvUM78wUfEJCOiYskvyyNHiAbvkCOR4SEU8bWii05CaGKjMUKrp/cQXkBmwHENZ8wwTZGkKVqOgjh2R8ctQX2dcWXSZEgJGs9fd7JPf4AeaipYE0eY5spfCWI7Ke5684NxbYF5rQxhSuP0SA9Cm8m8yRI@FyctliI2@jldRMdsI22yeZj00dZt5EmaZzoX8TBhOwMbdJuKWBdGuRdtysXREJX2tXjKoScdNvYRlFbm77E38kvRWodhSoL7q2B5Yk7FECxHA4ZP/WvITROYEKFBXrFr4rayY6Q2w6S8JAeqZDB9tZVhwZRHA@p0C2v8Zk23bISUSxA/MAIaUt@bqu3w9k0JUxEbvnjq/wckC3S/epTVhtRsd5eM9pDONhVyOdJchkcR7KMzQlORq7vRs3LZJHw@bYndVg2oKVz6SdtaGFGIEJkUDhk1Uvap5CmFsku4QooptChkN4d0F/Jm9H475NaJcT7FIlCjLqCgpBhJ2Ikt7XSF/F6Bhy9R/oBBPlucFbKyPlEEsjLxoaSUgJ02uGxGxOdCxVgyk7WnASFqOqJVPxgix0ixPtDel9YSTvY4gAWXdCOgFKT4SNt1g/zk49b@BGJqdR31J@/k5B8LyI8kw3UbIxkqWuPM2HF94hVrCO/BwNAsFzk4pmZD1LpZ5dBPI2t6Q5j1CMb22K77jC1/fP0f1l5BgiTgY@D5axGSq8AiMramT4DxC6fbcH@M3u3Rmy4kUy9e65Y59/vhhcrqQuBl8vfrcJEzkkq1k2I5JSl61GLCkrMDM66cirMkoLVKTBi0E0w8VAsAuLQQJAxEmdf3YuvzqA0EUSb5y/SDJBIl2GmDjfrs9B8M4cmskoFk7Semav2KrzU@/ytoC5lX6xD/mDzb@AhdpU0ik97HPGXQBFbrq/3bLHSeBsruVer@Vfw06o500zY@8W59tMcHvlTWEpEeB2Fqaei98j3BAhxMM0cAvwcQrt5FtN2PUkkD5KcgiVYk71WJqtoEyWeQLyA5UpWip6uNg6j4u6RzQRTAtgOZWXQkGx5aDBfSmcP4PhDdbjBjiuxZ1DmCPRyIBNROgENYOQ1d0rj3GorcRlmdycsqKCoVsJCHSvkzRmi8FwkJGLNTu7XMBFNDrN9Ddzm7m4jM6JaERCl@Riavm5yJfevfnbfx//lpwkS2vO6Rh@J8nfkhubSX6EB3h7pd7ukqXkNmbbeEjOHNgDw@Obv/0vlC/9DHAwZbYN/0rrCtbGLFnKFKnI12RpAx7ya2tQ7//99a/QhiXeseFVrEuttCDECooiFXdAvAvpooat5G3pcjiskF8WwmADQ9ibwwvaRU3XNnN0SpeURhV3ngx8pcxR5BRPdlkTshTikwxlTgErIy5QxAoyDFJZUHSFYbqhrDaQeUM0xS8vshsB7AB@kdYcukptufEiQIuhJd4WQQemuEbYz/NDKfcuoa07thLKpKSglpC4tZNj7earwv8D)

Sardonyx has `#` line comments and `#> <#` [multiline comments](https://github.com/SardonyxLang/Sardonyx/wiki/Comments).
`#> <#` do not nest, may be not closed at eof.
Compare with PowerShell: `<# #>` (not in the polyglot).

Main code:

```
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
```

zkl comment end also closes Sardonyx comment, I then reopen it:

```
#<<<##>\
```

Answer (score 2):

## 296. [CMake](https://cmake.org), 13870 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                        "'" # ##\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                  @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 111111111111     # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  n MMMMMMMMnnMnnnMnM MMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#|9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 9
#9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#   
#`⟪`⟪\⟫ bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__DATA__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((( \'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>                                            @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa













































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:pextsepsEx Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:1*F 4, _._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8uiogr ca34* 16  prstdFloat
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'

#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4@WL2R6RA3SIpEiABPsSHyCqVSrpXfatK1ZLq1u2mWCyQBElckQALICWyJFV09@z2usfeWW9Pj6Pd9vi2e9az9noixjuxs27v2DMR9tcJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOyQQIUiRV1bYj9sOCBJDIx8mTJ0@ePPluGl7v5z@P4MWeOf1pt@@M2Mj0RqztWhemq7KHU/bAsLycnpEk9LXrdscD0x55JSnCNMa8keGOWN@wu2Oja7II2Ops9t2x@iPTTTLPNFnT7DuX4J5hzDYv2aHdstoAiY2cc9O23pguuGUZe2T2rwfXI9ZyBgPDbnts6Fr2iFxzjD0z4KMzbp0zo@mNXKM1shwbnPKMPbf7xqDZNhh5H7omD7TNAFTrnMLMuxQYe@K4ngkxOC3T8xy0LIKl4VrO492nnyz419LsEwOQGvbNyUL0msZeWKbbXgyhs89PDw4WbTPsM8Wx2cFtlLQs2x2PnMPRIvwc2@2atsF0tajqi455IObI7BfShfScE7gdWC7kpiFyrTTLGXs8aJouEF9k4aU16qkQ4NThBGeO3Z8ycwLAAMcOeDNHzMLcYrl0Gn3C/8RsOXZ7Bh6sTIADcM3BcDRlCrMdwQPg5LjMGxotU2mbfWtgjcw261uAndMR2HgMMpydm9NLx4WMVzgrEiLe0GxZHQuDiBR4EjLbI7M57jJnPBqOAT2PtS3PaPbBW3PK2mbHGPdHSdYENyAe2V/2TFugZNldTMeLmQ1CsKEIcOw3NaCN1e8zQOcc0cGoPbaDDpdoj16bJmFpthHU/oxcAMnoe37q5yOeiwbDPXOdrmsMgFHbJtHg88NnzGs5LnzBjX55KVgHpmWM2M4Oi@4/fRRl1YCMqtuUApJW2BVjLOI7sgujPzY9NjCmELc9gsLFHMo/P4QE3ll0I1pi0UyG6WmWzbIsFLYC03NpBkWiCAYotXpGgzvP9ALLasD3uWgS4@m4RtfqmxxK1@l3ENA2cqyeYzo809lokru2KI5tlimw/DbbzrFteBZZUYdIEGKWacUc3Hm4AUIRMNDgzmR5TAFbIDtBEtge6xgDqz/l0IdDBN9iOY1tA0RAUwPIegEgFHWEMH@F4Y16QNiecQEglb51juLCDCQG5lYKXqmtrRSJLJSNPEqvZ/b7GCsQCkiUK7BtiDUPic5CzEBHvaD7ie/2KPmE13YabsBxG1JcAPKmgVJpJNU23PANYkgHeaODcNFBXuga2OtgziBU8JcHtzzkVT4grd4m2oJ0hbAaEhMFioY0gGAMsi6TZZB5WcjeDGZvLsMAT0BgO89AphQ0VsiywjYDchXTDEivATKY9xrIMg2Q0BAYZKkGeaoBIhowiwZAtUyOSSG6ahl0h7AZCAsk0LIQJgtmyBctjzeEg4zXIEoN4tT14oy1ADc9B4nMZYjn9Dxk3ja4AbF0wFUHbtEBW70A7hi2AIQrIEtu@4Qw@sOegbSAHEBGBlYDguQAJ4IN/sGsb2c4S5HvpjmyWtKNBKWK14BhieNLD5QAIE2YwbACBQaccU8skIBxEEjzwmrsmX3gIpAhLQPMyLZQ2lFy@HCskYpyFqop07nAipSK/1w0HomIpou1KMirtum6DP1CZeslSZh446Znvh5jXTvDqwPSyQTB2jGsfoAAFR1jRPUAvKMexDedR7vjOgMqXwMUFn3HGa4QuyCaLhHQp86lOUN9JrmM4bAP8hzsTSDE2OgDMpcG6QOkLoRj5QhBIAzX6lkAkKICuWq5ZotoL5IOoTMggedRLDG9ei@DUB6GqoUMGzogVD0MY4/7/RJUd2aLZaqptnmRQhtedcxXGYiDX5lAfShANA2oy6kyRSwCSPd0laqpUz9nPWcwnzQuXg6DpPcsrAL6l8YUcq8DksWcGAPQOBhW6zZU3APgGJ6DmBMer3gOWduxo6MAyqUL1SskOkgJgOwTTUbWwAR9zIEgmONZQhqFG2HWnAIrE7WyKqljHJMFQqnSIqG4RTZkwQsLVGztcQuphnFbNnEQVAge1VZVgMuVThUNUORc02hzb6hdIEYh/QhqOxOILlSBFgFCDcW0PdB2PJVZqBYCw3edDvAYVdGgakDQWTwtSjumPLCaqC1VIkoj3wzO@8xireGQgT3oJ4DWQboAdazzpcXegGO/57F@a@y6UzYZQgZYA/A1ajmdDjDtG3PYAxBs0GataQtKJaQSmUZqOySBWsOFJAdfmyb4sU1I9t6zb7CuCdSGGrkDmBKnzxIwHFISiBSGzWtr2wBKYRJawymRBcAEITqOo6J92zE94hHQZoISj5F5ZpdKBBSvzkwGDVD7AOYEjcAGlgWBI0oVwscIpaWJwahE5n9i2lBiWsCMUNYh@1Af3WUd0P1DlTUqd0arZQ5Hgj0ckmKWHVJojg5QoSFbRQBTvZ60@QB0sTkMJPAq@ZwTqsGNcxKuqOiTnmWgiBUNDKjTbTNQYRkXKP3prejBx8VC7PIr9DOHwSt5BQ5DKgmo3ZFsGI9QgqBQtFo9FIEjFDKkZUAhc8e3kw924ejdAVM6QdyIjQbSRlJTgRXisRqGAnf/NiB12EdY1TkL9DpncQdowxssgewESPbbYVs1ZaggC@8COnBsZwlUIGYAF73Mu1BeEDOeoNQw@gEzUnHx5vII5fSs7Yv1F1Sdw6HjQsngQmeKkoxnWYi7HN5OiQVVRBzazfM1KtQUUaznRyPe5hr2oR1ERQxLKuiTBkgKEGK8BQAyz@ExhhCmUk@wBH6XJPE5M0EVatsmqqSGO@VAIHlQK0NEU2a5LojBC6wbeNXj1yEq8SlUBUa7jZIVyUHlfjFyFTl6b9y0JovNjBZaql960oXhsg62MFzQNaAQxaIdLxovkz2FDDnJKWc4SlFQ/pTBI3lSIctjHWi0QEVwAILmZGq3YvJcEZOTTB6POgU5DgYMyFUz9jVjOFrE7kuwQ6YZnEO5pq8y60KtrSjwVNCOMEGHlIoOhgvqBRRC0LKLxXbTYNcgPVymTPYoNKqF9NbUbBCXabeDuAQhEJdwelUehee2yKCEajVMAXqnlFMlMUfA96QEBZTBIpUS9SdakJLH3Uid4ZZjm7oHWIxrIHF2FajoUAHECBkLdA6rZY0aQku5d8/XVzYqFWA2UKJAbLbjYeXe70dRQVKDZ5WUEBGJOnJORlg2YnFIL3q@4diAtgScWqmyq1HPhRJH3zcSeAKySjZysk9Ykc9PrfNxezGjbbRETzKWOtCVrNZILktQ@fPSUFlH1egcVUH5jyJVkXkxPIG@xbxkixkqC2@u6aHWWxGohHI4hhgIXl1KIh5U2M0Yem/a6guVgJugsHNp1AT0z0VLPRBESaET@IX2VknlQLA4cDjs2e7ppxVRFrljqmnZpTmLvtMy@mS9id5lP@zjw4fHu8ffaCyB0beapUWLlJUt5LGqHU@Urj1OZVW9tBmGMQP8qLEeNgac9yNLwpkpziSkKk1bULlMfHIeHX@2SBLQhJAcFAOY8V5QabgfULqkpuH1Fiph1k0kIMogiO@XKYfMhxkYEHV0N3x8no3fvMHMW0RqKOwRs/7Y4AB8y9Sh7YdT0XFBAfOdmh1eI1JY0EItG/s/Z6awTx@fT1BrXkSGVOkQy3xydLB/XCGwPcM7N/t9hbykvBHoUobbVoHn@@O2KS3zA@IPTC2WUGeIoz5NuC4lcKs1R@BZ3rIV8AEANnFUhyn9gZ80rwe47y2mjWyVVsAB9E0QFvXKsD7U@lBEQ3hgFdfClu6yWpQcZpVVYLW0xgpc56utVi5nbmeL4WqrNYuzHQY6IKXYcny90QWnc09BG3WmRQq1WqB/8vgW4h4pkdAUUHzMvD5TKS6vL2HrRbFY1EvtQQvN6ZvqC5J4MpPjqVTU7/hUWx61OUP@9yfWKJaO87cWB78Q@@7uof7I9yw66qgDgxoN2ATHmsnt4EBDywMesZ2@03XYFoTh2qEfIahNK5O523XsWzlkoCUmNYIjFyB/sb/GGEJdY72hhiOFCjdX@aiHYXuXIKW1fAaJRBQiUCnyr35pXBhArlm6Tw6/uQ@ViJZLpwNzmi4gQSgMkQtNrZAtWTAFIlIFPksTGIxi3CrtvoMSGkbARAtBFwTcnTkvtSSJqaaW@l@CEh9aCvlBhRrVccuJetQPhzILO0C8IVTa1H/UwhzwsO0/As7nPTW8k2EE@jRmADSrotg1Zni8AwICiQEFPzzoYQEE6mgLOpnsYCAFcoZCkeoNTXJQvbEnpDfrQUCFHjgOIiScsGEB0sGmDsEuCFwIzBOyyxPCYyKb@SSdQ5PDRmhNkxWUpjXi/XfO2MWOeqsdTht4z@jcD0CjxIXyjHr0oY3Pe1B4YEoFKHgGqP@g5EMzASQn9UmZlASDjwagnudhJxQ0XdIKdooCfIU92OsZdsvkbUFlgAoSU4b7LDpyU7vKN1OG8gYYdI3cxMTvhgenKNNPfQJQL0MwOkUtING7QZLHGZCnF9SWQseHflUmDaejHqRYaTHZqDhD017U57i2F4uXaQwlGlW/dCw7dhXd2NiIlqLVaBJM98G0g6b7aEqA6T6ZFDKhPxVNFCJJJnStUQi0q0dvaj7kSbyOPDBBqfDGGsaMWqmUqSeNmibeOr7jkBVAefCt4AvgROOVChrjcbl6id2wUDeH0r6HvHPScq2hIMHXoLDzb0GDDBEBVHesqV2zjHrneooMKi4ohCZWHzE3elZLn9XPrs7aibObaBJDx8tGBXS/GMQXG6hd1xkPQSjXsiVFq8fjtUypXm5WounoVixWUPoQkRGPf1yIJwxO61gUWp392NlZFEgqqFNr9VyCN0nq8XhAKMADWhRtqJtiUfWqAPE34/V4Igph49EktAUq0SjQpYVE8CjRqO1zJjqAxqWHnczQYg33F5Iwp/5mLK7fNIe9qRv2ELSooQbF3rHZQBsUBhqqDFdsb3j4sLCe0@L9Oo37g4oLG@YoC4dTLq0ljulZam7Q168VLpTOwBkZqc9VUIiCSGQvFd2IphQlJTNy4ZAo2U8sD4uwYZvO2Av3Iizt3MDYwfa0NwZh6Y@IJ4GrrKFktnoOi24@AOgs6MLFCgF7oxXep@0DaLdUuFGInh4eMewINe0RDRVbIBdxGJm3uDRCgosev98tlx@@VoPYyhSGpTEiq2s7rqkASSCERAO7NA1AqjIxWnxIrdpbfY7CdQ@iJKXaMkEiHvQdg2jLxXWor3c4CIUH3RuCHJttqQ/yowPiUeV54Zrt1JZEAy@O24MaAlKDklgPcmsgHFKON2yrowkElWKg9Mw5cs0N1MpL1tZ1Pd/KdUq@G3IFELsHmYQapw3qq@@kaOAYF5m8z5t8vv799OjRPm8XpcaeSy0rbCM3Bk573AcO5jrRsWl3k2wf@MmynYEFZPDDvznvHzvOiGvw8LGq1cUVYmsw7hvUnltscq0N13KaTp@aeeuCzvyPXc/oG7yB6bvufv7k8Omz56cnFbUU8pQyLgZr48Y@huXRcnoehscTaAjF7/r1OGPKmzkZ6y1/ogmKGeGQR4exmGYCeeTbb6O9X6Swf1TYF9B@gFNMoNUgWgj0GVgKj0XyiNNOcLReWF5p6Ru0X6lfBf408neJE1BC2F5pOtlfjDqdOesMWZ8rKJr6M@ssWfPpJ3P6XxilHPeEc1Hm/IQB5clPMCVl0Z8QXsHwYc/s@6MDx6CYYA841O19VJ9s8xJ75/m8ENNrob49tklCY/c5a/UM17vVJIEyNVS4bymyQeUE6rAUai7SZoqJ7qsylRRoEvBhB49LTwfUdmoZ7VT5YBQwhuXyQY8U71jbbACInWrZnymwyhvGFI0G3ggq4QYhKJk0JHcrqcEAq0f9ZRIFKUteqvbybKKnlbPJ9n495REROkw@O5t8nNa/kJMM53Ns3kt1zTJGt5Ja9M37mFo9EBssMZknGeTD2O44/bbCO7Qh/wFj6rH2gmHEYEYJCXywsVx/MomFA9Ri0g@Iy9A8lFtwF7KuettDaOZKAAhKwxW7Pk9eXLMa1GAXqjfsW6M6u1FHTqOHiR@NXXtxjgtXKV3XmHqSGIWusN3jTz6vpescgjQwsJO6wHNr4k@RAj0Y9B6ciQYmHEsfWSOq2GnQ0ML0aiogNaH@TEAfYPAIyiyISKQIUb82r2dp6ZgjUL1MxNybDpLMjN@onb4xGpk25y0@UrCa3LxLV0RToejvi/7BEktTJyoomha6AYpldnL6aP/4WAUO9WLRfexsLUGxM1o90DdWJdqnZDjxJfZxO8o@xjBxhrFAkYLGREOEB@YtA3NDcwJiR1HQNd0YWMaxn7QF1tQ1TQG5wiUIhDMiWiOiUQAsZsYhTQSstBT/5zZvOQk8SyzKEkRJIHfsXgloa8XVsW29Vj2oN0gNBS9R3vak6W@VzRiJr00tTvzjWgMc54EmE2mBkIZajW2AdCPfMqu8ZS9raaVYT2yyer3MR@8gIOr0NJ1OTM0yBD15VzcJSIHzoWiVdRYm6PkxUK8MhuL4acCzkuBbQNYdN6e3S6m8qcvxAFnlDVhwR3kRySUTyDiK/rQFEiE0y2F@tsL8XIhQsp5TI3th4ickx0cgSA8OMcR4KtlGhWnxuI8ZB/TCcLHpXGLPHM@zmn2amdbpW3yWR1BZlwRhBCSfMuHoylgwiG5YnqGcYWbMpiPySX6CEuROFQ20pDBlZBGLsyskJpFSRyqy62u0kNmmzogNZJwNyOl747dpQT4@dgDZx2J2Y1jnIKEhhp5RdJxJst94mx/bQRfeMEhdLOi8yoUcDsd1Tss@d6iHODA10qqWQz0zCD04798O2bG8Hj3mvAY4cL/6Kuy8QbNDjyUeqKNUDMGRBXXBCQ0bstNIHdOLeuOWxDw/7DwXbdPsjO0ujVegmSmv7/CpFAvkudNsWqu8AhFwJon/XuINZCWWPF3NqppferCDB6pFkJ@8TTRL@uKMBTZHd6ikRhBKvP/Lt9pA/9u504P6Cns2A0MDNAXMKaWzMrNEUPygx/KM5SOf475lEGHIdBfIluFCkox@YFgOmobtFAX0jQF2QoocB97EB@iia9iMY87HEPz38kiWdcPbILdbq/wuzODgUVGHMTQX20QErnNZJgUiIcszwZzwTttQwx0F7t1I@dMsGDEzz/feeDTmT1CH78xEa4j3urIpfKZzRlMzoUFqNC1zTZa7xvm47SjD826gFueX@J2lnkaNFNBKxABSA43Lk88T6FpdqO799ypvs/o1dUmvu7jCs8feUGlS277Nv6ggDNbE4Pb5c5UXS6xCCAyrqWb16fGenCigA6OI8dMUzk5TQkSzFsjcN5pTVIV6H85lwVgkSJxKK5FIZ1YMRg2Hq8Nj@5TCF4vLQ0/UFqfHsp6HFJ8Bp/C@OUqwmBN3R65CdWUNjL6it0PGlcJ82VDmLa/BKAiFMS8g0@ixjsmxQmqN@4Y7M61h8Rke/uDEqn5uUW2Istxy@paHBbq/Smr682lmceEcRHqExkytZZRsQ0MU63ElMC2XAk5rhPPMVrDVe8g0Pr8LZ9GF@ER1VhGr5VzivVKD6EFjmD@XV2pvlmL1HvJJ6bf6BlTlK2uEuV5H7NW8g1cvLc@kx3LCni9FdNTqL7WfLwV@f2K4f/AuzvasvuOxE3quI1DXBSrw53KeDtPSMmyFetnD5jViyB8YnWWo0e86/XyhmzLgsTLXx24HRb94v6@QC4SUpt0hpHwNyLE18V4p2s9T7vldGURrO1ycFBcyrqlll0kqMaizOnXQNsARweUpO0gXKKSa4n2IKyLGsZxLY@q/f4HaYxVp/dpjOCWNGhQ8DFAsgGHkci37F4ktuz629vsJpVtgt@9KRChzz/sm1Ff0vJWlTE9rHxhCS6ffX0R1@mNzbC5taxw1vzRxieCadsb7I5UWydgUQwA46oDz2QNfb0Tj8L2wxqoav9YKEwNa7ebd2sy8UBuCAj7E1vMzMDxDw@0QXXs8nMvVuQaafbyeZL2hX6Sd9hx26PKhcqhwh7I0p6J7Jt1rG028kYezSirZdDotdJjQUM7cx7rGVCYI@6XFn3MRk80s5plfHL5zQ8blcRBZwvOWVoogfVXbnjwXiynbss3RFJ/vKU2bjtP/kJwCodq2UBsD5ZLm563LsVvqjph5zma9Fx72eTQ7q/oteG0jmpdAH2w3r8v08FjTe@WmgqOpAxzpmv9c34MTGrm6KxZcqondQnzGXn@1Lik6RDS1oG6vLXVcQ3WaZt/gr0k@uw5eUc2shTcvNMQoMI4a87Hi2Rh/ZEEoDadALKsNDZWeOTDpc42ib7S/HHv@a6WniYP3KueJabZSk32ztcrD0AK5YONzbnA6pCyNHBuaWCPD7ZrYVOnj9DNhu0oC@8OJS4l8ODC6Jl9/vk5SzvoscJoOb9nNjMt7L0p8ak4Lgs16mFezBBSqc3Pq@e@lAJ9MW5Cv48HdPW4Lhb@F3aDvUdpXzXu7XcXaPadn98wen2wafK0qHMCPI75fwDrUAetur8VINIXnxYbp2Xf6/fehJ4pGLigdp7MUp31cMYfLPT4I7tRogoN43dl/Z4y47EDDylLTM8dQL3nOyBmaCn2t8trHvh7@XCVD/dHvX7QTaW1THyjiv39R@He2LbuGMxoO6dUY9scePSioQgsd79KbOnzOC5KdOW5XfeMMmqqwVMWEGBp0Xy5imtao1cMFppyzza7TbPWsu5BumsbIts5Tfq8P/3yvtitSxmLKI7RW@xaQ152qyC@VsPsJvg5XZbroQOLVWmBYo68s66SjtZzK0DhvebxDFE2shH3CodLIV3yWaKls6fXYGs2AhiZJBT28fGQCDatwF9MyVmpWNLF6JobFdI2VXEpKOirkipkGhUdb2b80N4EuVMQyGf5YhVA4lYRRaMLLh5BbTCqiDkIr1HUL9nP8NTcbamklZ/fGXe@2wOQ99m1Q0fCxVATudnGbGFy65zCv71zSVDVaHT1b/xfqz4bazLDFa1UG6P0UrpmCdwO0sbG5dsAlt3bEhfxpfcVwLHg14AWZOl7Zu9a3hh5/MqWzcpxOTJ@CVvriYCKn2nR5M1tkWdvs8PERNN2lPA4cGsEF7URp4Wg/dq@jmOcqGRdpttMFca/02cyz73eVQrN0ZtJyxghqU@WLp2bXwOndj60Rzg9dwi/EzMtmNN0J@@tjw7O@PoaUrWJDXADOxyjd8Eph/FoC74nRtVqfzmVEgKQgsJhcyl9zBQOtbufFZc/ycHZVYFjTZYUsx5kYua4BLYolPhc79YO177NSz1dVLfW9rOPdGU5x8cmUTOv63K0R9b@K96pG5ap5Z2uRuBwPhmNPvJbjQPO3wv3Tg3Oy9y4tAK68BqHLekZ/tLwPO9QZC/qZqC5nxlV6@jetvtNl3yykGahzoJ6h2r6EcR5Cxf0MJw259hJOpLjfc0wUu0AULvu815C3ZoYplm2N1vfzjEY4gch/Y2J4nYKLIlKP8ak@@FAIyulyijy@uxUwW@l4R80PnHfijN2WicZg@4Jwg0HEau75E55FrWGbl@H229pxHagoHXs8UtyxvbZWyK@tFUpsUsiH2IDFvr7/5Hk8zA00Qfwu/dSEZuHY609nppWzCRaYzLJBRVstR@d9@62MR3y3lWOanXxHmF3cEqZF4vqRs6wl9GzqmqP3bkqB8B8PHpktHFO8M@6nzhPHdqA2GoKgHBybfAnx3CyQ5QEx2GNcJAv0ad8ZzQmBXVEJcW3DGJpNyN/@zPQ@dREH/MgYGSuqIuo1pJZhYLqTV6x@03S/pO7AkHlVY3ceoU/NCbU6VjMML4PKqNXiyjL21M2VkbmxHG/oODZ/krRNw0t7sl6qQFVAj/cfRVdx7v9cj8HSltt8Uo8u@BQSs83XuK9Kq2s2nT5/rpmwZFt8woDhWqaXeoxLpskun2UKaF/eWhmyvVaGzBpNoMleGB6N4C9vhMxAapMPmB/UM9yWg2NkwrBm6k5onfMdYjpYTsBnFTSB8BOQWEZrLHZcuwut/qA5oMfKpkQoN4/NJi5EatLmACNjcjszeZ@RWBkdmu4VrCf2xRUW6jyLPYN2SvzuamuuhTVPVWtID5LUKwfSaSaPYltm642B/WkO0WvWaz3nDmlOPSXjil7sUDGi/uWUQQtnl5ak@XltoND0TWXUc01QfkfrOr79XRuWjJSMByYOP8@Pz6xUXR2vR4l1lo@0B8LVNRWxYxjIkmD3MK4fKrsrNU8ED/@jh19LQSXcyGf9nQxAdN09tg/Ij11bvN6HA5853qhjTY4Ab1yRsEqcYLJyEARevGSgaWtVIiD37HGf90t0Q5OyBm1qjim0a6Wi9Elcj0zFtC8U2ldqcjtFDl9nltrFLRBHZlsRy6pxDEJ57C85C7yJ95Kh1bBsxJmgWooTdpLPirmhy4h76UsG0LeckTL06J0aes8OHx@dqkNPW97q7@FKjVt63Nw6bb2QDnVWfWm4oZFQPletbXmj1MMTTdl7fKiihxX05mMdCrxwzG7utbJHVGw4aKSMla0gdDVHyxXET0@fPE7MVoWy2F7PdQZmPOy8d3KSxFUvXztZ6hwOfQClo@NMVgY/3Ne0@BL2fW7TuOEq6bkkplWQTk1ojQIzfsq3ebhTuWo5Q7N9Oh2an0PliRLce8/o8ysT@dS4sLpYCllxJaGooLKims/GQ9O2obFtusF7VX6eW0OUli16pfhr5UQV1BwyKTezXHtYNxdgUYthaTFH4cMCaenb3DqyFCgZ3R6aUob390VM07RVdD4xOpCvLLcys@Y9LBs57jsX7zHIbIrGixJYKSPgKsW6c5L5tjIA0Z3CB3bcC0swNldOkFkHILDOLy3wl6Y9NWyFRrnWqRclCI3T3dZ6@ab5HkNVwdyfC9wGdunoXzDfnsVaZIzfEfGpGwqyt/fw8K4Ax4KW63198vQ5e2Z4LaN/h8cwxuZ7YDzTjL5UsN8KN9RaOdDadgGUvhZed7i8PJfYieG2HXs6uXt4jpa9YtVOW5QGsPCLPJl9a2Itq6tavF/r2W0nvpjleGyHt070kmKBPF@DxlcFeaq/v2UsZiQS8fj8FsrhNVB89Y@Bm2jTwh3we33NNsT6HHAIliyJVUG4LTWoBCaupZN8EDW2eSXW0JRK2g2uI5JLMhNrnII9yfi@WpXNGO4IBKgy5VzDTeTZpr8Ah9HGsOyakWoAskjLpeFLTYVXRJbFyiRWgmifHT7bPzndPX1@UkvXb@S4WH/HUTMMiMxfmflxpi1DigQxoMbmm@zRCr4@REeb1qJK4fnJYpCwhZRV5lI2S5N8H8NsXhlGKkUL0VLKDeCnyDw2cgX5gVYctp9iorpYR1ji67f6RFF5k4OWKU7IiRJLL4t4aHgeJEu4L26bTa4sk0FXHrHYFw04uOs4bRGjZ7K7Lz/Gg93Dx8@P95mP4IwVLq32qFcp5vi2eVgsFRPyqWPRmHaFRUWQKORVpRI9iAJhomqUlWj5H21ZB9wL3nzq4MJBEXqLxTYJPlAwGmRK6r98K3UTVXF6Vhz8Rn2kokxQHj2wU1zS82e/2@ZbuvoL@f294d0BqcO0YFoSy/VWLNZDilJxG67eIZ62UKV1ecHerbNd9yXa0Re48hK1pMX9WeK0ZQLf7l9sn@NHRAzibwOJrXncCgeaIhcWLsrjOHRwZ5p5VsahQYYLmVW2i9vfA88D6yMSgPrYHvHdH8Ra8QjwkRqIiSTbJGT5JsRyyGN0ZwNYuWl2LZt5NqhI5qjEvgQ@wxZzia8MVZRq9FYQHzQ/90DpjQb9kMdbW9l4qbNR6t2vfi/VLTMwT9IP4euXxVcHzL/CzS9TmNe3t7uZxR9GwsRSx7HmkQc0R3qHdvq3@QrcGbFwVx5f/jFrAFlzQZRG7zwG/lRsJs/gxGqfQ0YBi0EuiZW3PD7Trcd6o9GwlEohG@Hog0qzDc0JH/pXgclTr8e4mblje6l8Lp/VUoCkcuEDpI0ru7isiQOMx0vA@NKFNay8agJ77ewwGWtcs5Iv89xMbRovM/KrANFN8Ctd9hC5GoMwEGQWAtyqIhhUEgktjkFRHkW1KIqitgO1B7ljLYPftiCEzGJALE4jE3dCnOCRDyN3ir0y434bt1SyndCmxpsCkKJBFUSmuCyJxaJPnRGwzNwyWb5YFKe@8JoKB4o9fqQJ7b@OPKjeLk2zNU7@7smifKlY7jmoTHqx0gvnrfwCQZwgiJK8jGVrL9nZ6MyupzhvMmDTHwuWDTOzDeZ/luqu4Fme7t3bG23FFrfJQmKxBye2g6rFASSGxfSUnklp@fgsSdns0iSJFIloIDm4/P8aogPRBGKiZVpfOkNvd2//8GtHz05ubSZFPqOL3kCSV3cSZ4qarNUDQzScrPkseXiQOnny8MDPiBnS@ZAEBp1EpERbl5JZiwFBzuamLiZtGYaLqVuN8Qu@gG0R34y@DjUKdAsPLf0B8dL8MOWAZnkvRq4XllErl1uH0gxeKgR6jy/RuYVqLH51U6vvVM/sSPQ2JywpCC8j6hYWAjCdeVubKWT224nDhAVHD53ioQleuCxmlpdFeTODe5rgIsGRcz7bzUVYhBxC6fWjAREpqSnf68rSd8R16dmeQzo/GonvfhLe8yGEcD69juIhUKf@KUsoRWY7ponNwnqG1@tbTcnfa4NvGubvbRTsF8b3yYjFJbGnLo84Js5dmpQmKg35xuIo7QhWkq3bf8yHF5egQKO@9mwMzdRnzpDvsUhd@49M33TsgPh9NOZjhCb72ngA/jr0OjapmwUktwKBgZLRAFWuP4GUENuPTRK4wRvEV8NNyETC1UE7F5vE1Z45aVtdkO2xeBIk2seaVmfBFmWYaNqSzI7KlGezXFhbFD/BhVdhsn/QPnWTGQJGzVAtu21OYtHLaLxUh/jRPnr54iIal5fxEu2XJzaQay9unBegv62tlyTGSJROf1e6ZdKiWLwtJcBuETDf8cXf4L1YVHueROd0VFAXPxm5j8EIakSsMzCGLDa2@a44KqPP2FnMTtI2IkqVb6xls0SCmkjwIgeVUcgOmXj9HTPsKYulKsAEaOvZbXy9sYaspqlqHcwUSZxt4sELe6Bx4Q4TcQnaqhCkRGAryELQcACMeCFROYNDGHSXcOMPl/YWWuJM@9BTR6WDNKFUs@o9Fjo/Y15zlIvFksjQealYZMB9t8WhmgKwt@Scr8sDdcUKdqAZNGhVKTIT5LclXoTijXBEPhVL3wGdSGgzPH9FPANYs63qWj0X79i@DWUFN/EoPT89aBTiKZkFS@i7rtXG3hLayC4SNNrE7tpQTFNzXqNl3kb7BIPh3kgNvkYft@45oAIjL4jUSJgMi6fJzXhT09ZyvQgocgF8ZrECEOsMGj443ATMH7da4rZc2P/853henRzbvJ/PNPoXiWguXYaHVs6xHPt480xRNmt6Ll15sFk3jNGZzIxUduvRhdnrNA@7qTNZZhmWTaW29Pzr86GW33pZU19P6nKtUEme15@ds2fPvnjbeBuXJxdT@SzGtiNs7@ha1iABkdI2KzK8l150kNTSa1UTXY4CUBaJnJ3hOXTytpxK1aJ1@JPrK7i4v1pVrar362/fxmvbkKbJ9CyCxzuxowfz8GK6Hj@xLCvFzoZeuw2302N1fkBhhF@JRExhwkKpcTs2mHTIbrJrdrvjfWPK7a3IGF8HIxH2yTdfvHiBhhd0sTfHIjyHzvw4Sg0jF2F6Wv@zn27cJK@eNXb@7NuDlLmBryN8fe/mCZpPtNzHGxsfP3yYzSaBStz87JvPvrG7u5t9lMw9q@XuZ5X0xs6f/snGhq7v6KmNuudp9Wjt/PwLWU9nZfXPfhJtPHv2dc/DbMErwzQw4rMAt4Y61Tl7A9d5h@GfzG/aIbOB5mbnDdMjbyLA1pEp/RoRxkthhbSk8LXBtOr97f/6g6PXkVGkqqdeuPAeRV5H8oUIN4IBvjL@10WkGtlBb/mbyDRVqVTAuP1f/x2Er34N4KDLdAce1ZwPKz@NVJUKBbmOVPNg0HQd4v2/v/Wtu3t@HtTgkrPbuny/DtcWXTsSbl2kpFOpBd9a4Z52jzF71BuZDr4s/rLhxYyyDe3u41oikairClxqgwKlNE0/oy6bMHNRj0sksC4zbsNCdjNOETbg9iJCXAVsRZzFzcKCmI1bvFj092LJVX7xj3MdS5H8xgPzUbUKIlCv6lvVBF0bZ6US0byRYtsF2XEeYE9W9EyOslfssSBxVU4XdDmZTD5o4KmfbIKUVCaRGdkYpwyLzNEzwmZfLGwVYX4wNvPzof728frz//3Pf/jnP6DfD@n@j7i3k922OqmtWmwrXr9oVPnFqlW56spXZ/TxgKVLhVIhRa4goOrHTEt/ch3NZaInWDkEl@jZjARXtYoPHw38qka4TZWbZnbCpRp8kI9ZkOX@mJBIPlEjUPWKiS5K7aLOqn6Cll21B5BNsr5dlOtVPacfQdZpMmVckfU2PeZE/L5adh@uDfjRf2MDBUNgg88NvOh5n3tdcm0E2Nx9LaIqRWq1VN2kyiLw9GCjtFEo5Ut6qhG2XrjKq6BHLsJyRN1WC6oOkuNtbYMdc4avs4R/nSXuvJ6rakMYyeDgrSjOJCJF/hGuqsQiV3DV327V3m41/KhrorAmdpR6NSEwgpfaeFBPKDc3NfVlolwW/51qYCzTlSgzNEJK6jeKsvMSgNXmwUazTjTvPEDoHDg91cbLHQCf2KntVJw9ulUqLkr9ZbW2Mw9CIPfgQQLF7AMAUN2ss3gisakoG7WVaQCA9RiDJgFk4M3OTfWmtnNzs7MD/x163og32N7s3PrTa3at8DNzryNHndVS1bPUmWCbOnyrqSraqKkzMFThDf6gBpIiClQr7Im4bBv@cD8RNjZaoc0TtLT5w@Ze7HAgEQwuKbLFtiJDpm1nwMTMkralZ1K5ycf5fdCxanUFm0IVpablc3WFi75XKispfIdprZCPqyjbGk6ngYvCVPZKilyj1gCFuyhFUlvYuCjyNkaRrIpYzFoe4zZSBKgAnFtF2yt8UDF89e6r/xXvs3df/T5rvsbf4zf4ez3C32kLf8ev8cdO3@DveIS/J038PfPwd/oaf7tN/J0O8PfwNf6ejPD3vIs/KVIBrXfzfrqfbqW1c@0cDBZLuyzdS/e0NgrbtMnS0/SUpQeO1gaTCb80mKx0h6W7LG2nbU0DRzCMWHqEpg68uvDrABQXflY6jcDTLQax9FGE0/kJ9L4GoRI/k2os@soE7VTV1LSatxp13Jm69uosWsdNDvViljWn5sbZKxbxQJktR1JnZyneLGd6tozbVt/cNBqPdk93G40UCoKzJ87R7H90NAh/rv0PjpwnR87Agf/R0dGTM1BvqokHCeUBXJVqYke87keq5ftnJQXLjV9EI6md@2fVjILmfAJKnY52iQ@8ZhDhXd04k6IM1IXLMqki5cuL8mWZDMEnGBrlwIPwxg1gWRYqDNhAuLMXKdI@LuG6uCRrfKDxEhx9EzekXlyeoVoO7a3gD@QIf/4D/K3/b/2fPGexWj0ObZ@rm50YXXH8xeNXN1c34lmNx2LiI7YDP7SAbwxydVNFI3m6AlMtFq/Hb264HTxj8R0OsIpx7FQp8MwjCIFIECfFyx@xf9g3xi0udgZt@tBA@dnZJJ2Ol5v@Hqw4SGRc03hlvEwnamw2a1r9T39CO@3ej5OnXLZc1rYY/9Czermc9b@2C@Vywf/YjMWKt69q@r6WBxUjm43Hy2X4uO@DTcNnALYAYP2PHEA1PaNFhb8cuTo8oj1oQVbkInHc5ZlLh1iatqrGUw@ickm@dy8mTkq7vxu/d08vpq@vA5vhEKy0OatGo225jQbaZ66v5YZMA9fFHHynC9fXIMGicceNPcXDMiCimKKxj/UqxVl0XCDENjgzLaXPsOgZnjEaubE31jAp4@ROT47TXvbptOOeRX/2/W9/@yxaqciKTLZZDQFgLCy3s5PPVqv5LJjzBaCUvHnFj3XoJopa/GYzJXNqMHkzGhFOWmE7zgVkFN1ZZIfdr0IB9/BiVzcRynaWzcVjIGLjoOrcRPDHrbVikduzbD5WSBTFr7IRZ1WoOfkPG4eZRHZre@tBndFvsuxCsVy@MivaTeXKLGEv2025JU4hwlVV5r17mSLQtJAun0m@MK/Isow1IjzQcv/po0ZDwgNShm60RhmeK9ZrmL76WTRaKj8g5tAKORaJloU/JQpVBSsUiQyS1cElk5B2rGv5PTP597PHu3v7p0l9Byp9/WB3L6mfPH8Y0fAzN/sm5wx@H@/vPjp6DgGePd7fPdn/5PDz/efPwN5jl7PLl7biOXuHTUu@L9kL6Uv3jWGahjk2zcbleHz5mn1pWQ0LiNgfW5bldF3mmQ3TNIfgzb/KcLcsz/jyS8Md0sXe/fi7737837777e@/@@3vvvvtH/7sqx9@F@7fhfv7/P39f1vM4fNnX/1Pv/Put34bLP8j3H8E909/9tWvf4vf9P3HcP/nkN0fizvkj98SwPrln331g5/87Ktf@RHc/0rcP7p9/@pPl98//M7qG8P94HfW@/n@v4P79zgs3@/3f4vb4fuW/9/i/n7lR@9@7d/z/5@KHxp/@92v/TE@xMc//9Gf/ud33/4Pul7403/z7rvff/edH7z7zrfffed7777zT/V3v/5vtHT48TvvfvgHf/WHv/dXf/g/0v936fl77/N/96N//hf/21/8H3/xh@L@Kdz/Hkw//Yv/ADz7t3/wY/z/4A/@9o9@jP//5V//7R/8y7/95f@ZDL/BDf/Pv/q3/PnXv/qf/uY3v/dXP/3W3/zLn/7Nb/zBX/2fv/J//fp/@uv/7vf/@n/4Nlr@xk//6o9@@S@//d2//M6/@Mtvf7Xi@d21z6/ew/6rfwSb98fzfeC8T7o@1OarXwifvw81ZrEAnwCD/7N3v/5LwOO/xr/@e/iCf@D0veBjzoV/fG/2ARB@cyFQxCzNVwsFvZDYAu15q1gUVUPgvEMhf/bVv/hJEMUvzUOdc4MYv4flcs7te1ii3/34W@9@8k/f/fg33v34l1F2K9licjepaOu7NEHoK7n38Ice8@/jj/Fq5Isv4DFJUH@cksAv9oXw8MUXX0iT6xQ0fNIPrsH2C7LiF@NO4MaEk@8m7HEaZNgPN6Z94yZaX4ejBrMmOpc3JJ3e@JC0BL4TG2ACfLekXAa@CHV02fJTk5Bymu8QEbC444QGESbwl7JFFoFAk0liAm0iMCQmLAFODxOsUqlQ4MqEvMInhpmwagG8T7DLp4LQIRAPk2wUEMTkIUGBkJXEMWtsVSY8YALhVQkCIYdWx7Kmy4lC5RFEWJk8YggLgRPYV68q1UJlUkVwbwkFiCjxkHBCYJXEpPoWvisEE8JJkUdvAZVCJZGoFjBCTCSnVbJBcWo5ShylPcEo3WjPaHbn/QeMfSxrBZl3Z28gwbhvfCZmvu/TEMt9cD9LbInk0N830r1FBN@gqEQsPFswsg0eXngAuIqiqiqDW1EQmwfgPOGgEhQtvBIJka0ADy8fJFhABmNeJCh/E/QB8UcqWx98JarsAy7eMVrIy42ENtVBM5Xz29gz@k9uXf/NP1l2LbfFS@I03dzclCJVOSMf0SBDAtqu7nmJH1BwzRsIJSbnizJamzT9mNPY3HxGze@tR1vw1OC/v0GzghOsTMTZjGLHUJTxVLOPE/x@8GCLfQx5QO@ZncSURMbJYk8vknsnkZB1iLXqJKSXIAklKEQE6FpSJxUa2khIySRjaiWCbuzo6EigRhYvK1ICyqCe0fAbe6XH43EEQqhqUgWa8rdKb7JQhUElV/FWNzHnqSOL6Xq2DFp@maEVCyvlGrTe0PLt27fAMjQzoHQI7SomJgno2QI5ggVfqdbvT/0p6Xq2KPFGJdPy/HjQGJ0wFmdxicXYVlzic0g5EsGYY1QvFKJoikOeqLEtf85IXiNexR4z6jALnXONLZ1CLu477h2xvaMnT/afng7rdSaJM9kb4rDndTwZw3C7Tx/xKeZ6MY9oRGo1jPm0pKNMlPZLacQjcfjo@PCkxDhNRA7FAkjxMvUdClIUNSkyHL7YiYhxdRnPInDkE3yWZumP6cUMRlgtS5GWiQo7MBz@WVl64nUfOhNo0SZlOanlccw4Tl2JTPqGUypV3mrZbQne9D1muDcOX0gHMgInIqs7O0Q0qXqlUO8rGiGD81K1KiaoME2qnuyfQoDTI6bpaZVBe/cqu61nc9mcnsnnc9u6ls0Xs/lcIQN1Uj6d03WtmM0WC8XtG6n6BZuoiKsC5n6lb9rdUW8Tp4XIZ2k5RI/NWjqJPz2TgSdATGq57frGRv9KQQTPiC2ucH7PDXxeKUiBj@Bi0kcS@wis4II4cNIOEzOmDo/KYtoKLlmP8bkrspaDwh2XzoCRODhpGL7Kc19DKEvQ/g3dUmTjm98csWoV2p3K4YEUAcHZY/48DsVqqz2VmKo9dk1y7TLWtj638LgKtW15w74xhYKaVqXIzc1NByAdHuBgH33yEG183rTIpgnmm4kh/f/XP@C1w7d0qeLEfMdoV3B5EG0kAcUtftWutJ0WHWFT7lRqdTqRqNxWm057qnqjKYhBkY2VaLPvtM6jvqOFZwTiirdKykipDRQuI6fRqFSiqVT0vr6dK22k3JRKO1ixWAcK6309vw2WZza3jXXAJoc2L@etiqW26iP1BJgWwuklPZ@72RH7ulUhTYhaFRG5EviVbMc2b3BKfcnogCS@avF5UyVZzxXkcq08@97Oy@X6zYOB2bYMdpbGadRXSwPm8/KN7w@iNqG40Sqd2ADPUcHFGKX0WTq@InAaAgPKhKm0I7aSqdI8oBoIjToeJV2r7/ibzFQlJum6omeUjKZoGfzfYdDx//7@dfjr@IRQGV06xYVWTyG7QTja7DHudjty2Knj0MFGD83WCh97PYMmPO25juf9Pfw8NOxz7vTI4rubBE6fGrijuTewRr0VPp4PB7j4zHT/0SDsD5qAIPIg9/AQHm7fcZZ52GbPn61I5ZNgPzEgBt9QDLwfH37y6Wnofbq/u/eplGcPj54@WnjlhKcce7x/cBp8bnNXP2guAPGN/cePFz/FK4LVKHYKbrDctm/QJJwxeQ@aMveEMZefGdNofMEX81heMIOPr9oqSaf@Ch8qH1bTZC2@HnAiTfiSdqHcaNtFSRoy27lk22nWdvp9Aw9162yAZc/AlQsmVtd9OnsQo7503H4bipi5IT3BRRJFDU@uQiSkTwHIYNyi9aPWSMINUtp43Bp2QjfxxOgxHmm4whJeaIVG1@r2Rmx06fgepKZhMLg/9ILwZvgarbcY8TjI7pZL/7Z3KSIZIyNSKAPDltv2@N497ZkLzF0tpEuls/QNcFfloVlunpeG5mTkmUNvfwLMxsbsObC/4aKU7G2msGHMNnNyviXrJW3rgGWTrKE2IsYW0r5rVWrsBFSV@vCYFcbUo9oyMtkt0F2xxgd9jbbPkf76N38XeXgrBeIqoskyzt3c0CSV1Dy9WMgVihm9kCwUC9mcls/lkpqeBC16uwiKTloraPlCrqglC9liJgt6E7jmittShE@QSW0RSHiXAKzdwsOWdkhTVHtVKcJHJdibmBFnESP4HjPZhDAyHq8LlQ0uDtuyKrKeZVqaQSMBIBqsxSIHB3vpgwNZfogfOAK7l5blNn7kCun09kNZNsllD3Q7XZYdHqaAK9PlEf9Ipx/uyfKYA8BN3WS5hx/7eeyLkGULP/Z2Dw4wng5@6BgevJ1zF/7R9z@2wZuNH5kMdWbI8usAHPjb5RFlCdN9/MA40eWAu@yBmyx/4uOTTgOEY@6PQ/jUT@vuriwf8o/dXXTZo4TnOKqf4ccuXbIMGY/lQ5a7YOhirSfLTTBiKZHlFphaUwPs8Ggr3PnLHhmyPOUEQhLJ8oR8G61zWW749hjNp59@avRGbbPLr6nL3y1ADVysyXj/oPnJJ81ut@lOd/c/OUaXvb1Pjc507Da7TRGs2YDLgTDgcj6YLl6A42GjYfSXunwGLvaCS2PaMBG3hvEacBJXFyMZNPbAZQ9clg3ocGhwDcBrE6@HA3g/NJrk4l/kQu9JsymXkVFx8T6dTwllho6KTA6MluuU8XtS2WAsGosmp7V8ul4mBzYATS1dvqGDKWN0Hjg2akGnuprWJpV0vTKpbOt8QkAnJp9N9JwlJzcG97UiqGHGfU3PJiYlXCTqdKIsqmj3Y9q9rTexp6BuZbIl@ez@fUWuafX7ulYo5bdfbo1lOV7C5/3MdukNtLmi0OTDR7y2Xb8Put0syPZ2wkjppe3tePkGyDGCWrSJjc1GLHZpGufxOKKLTRNIAj8Wc0rptMqd2CQ5qXCs2DRenlS0Mt@UhqVvwWrjDmjj1shxOcQugJvcT5fo4E1ZKxZkiD@VisXjIJlIiMB7NtPmxddPz09PvwCZBY0@0WR6xk9zK4vPTz7dU6EVJb5w5zL1AFVlx1X3ULDMufCNtXyrU5C76qdQFYLa6tvhtH3X6av7E2jIor7tO/j70ahiFxH19NM5OCiEecy46rFMa@ztlslwYzerzYxKFUxGG5rqJO6M@CVVwo1qtdKoDPjZmdUg1Gf88PEZmEOP4x6sxaTgVziVXTg0Kumbmf@n4wF7yD3RWcB@sEblIdTq6bKNG5qa@LnJJpGJVG3jnm8PKw@vxiXsKrkpmxUTzxiVI7hS@r5dGdue0TGfmS4uPT482oR6BifAQxvBZPFNdkYnku6hUn6jVF1mz@ESM5RqE3sX5ixDn0g@0NC/7hPmipZl4EDqDbRwYi/j5dfw5W6yWFt9CI2SbLkde8gacbBKv@q86jCd5bNlOqgpRrCMJFGQTvuMV6qfga7DAZ@XSoCM4IRzAIoxAVyrTQ5GfGjdlLuVGnq@xseOIst1Rald16WqoryQqlB0y9OIUfHGTdoZlKWbmp7Olydgp21nyz3WrDRfTspuZQgNbFbuQ@6LXgW@2sQoAw2BUgDnzTWLvfulb8V3lFyFW5YJ2HUf9Amo5yuTWVZlKjU9m0/q@Sx2QuQzcGtJPaPjpPGkni4mdQ1qa6jFITzc2/CdhRv8QGWua9hVEevHZMbkZHqSVrWkZmpJIHr6ldV@FU@ex0AxIaLFkyNnH085BQtkJGBe@oS3EU/oW/1Y22HGjkKsDNKkTOk0kj02tOCBcI5No8/9xxWW2Yr1N2PoafN0PNyv1Uul/cnw6@AUU17fzye204k38Xg5BiI0XvHM11K1LFVR@BAVhhvA2qIHhnnjQS29Aem@UhrKDWT3aFPb1ku18WZN0SCB6evujlyV6wxy7IYJZQeFCtd3ZhrLzK6B2jWeF8y0ol6WVBpvp@i0mF5ctWghLuH23QKgNBQCEanLYmeyv/oqFo1u69FoPFrGjtoNWfSvgRTkRw@DOI7e0@7LoGPJJbmoo4eZMKUFNumwmnUjYbuZZYtS5Eq6ubrZgeZniqZegUrINsikqNUHUqTEGOh6Z2ILh9QGYx86oyuxU33J32c45xLgSrR1UI3VaZaFaWGbiX2OiwnvsyggZriDmq5n6jV9G@pAkKu@V13XytgNHcFJnWoVKO9dAX47iSrOwv@MTadGQvEpe4@xbmJTokRHFsm@W9ntHu@W/a897Pw6k2RZLkflyFU0Er2Bn@RPUGyZQIa3ERILbO/K70Mp4Q72MaPEhUCtHn/71OpfFTIKb@aDXLq5iWym@PoBna8fYJHQCgLAzZ9K/dkrPQdZZDu@BTSDRlAhQO2Wy2EvXiT1auh9Uy9knhwe2Y/cA9MfQcg25GqEpTUFJymXS8I2x8cV5GJBl/XzZIQ9iJQj7FyJaiWafs2GJ8WX2y8LL588P3p@dCBFzjauNxzs4WU@Vdhb@2tfB4/RTDbK2FklMqlky2JeTbWqaDs6uw@VAMPjoztaXklfVzn3Vskhr4PLu1/6UXayU4BvHRTcEuRgLqFXq9qWzuKR4buvfh8XxV/tf777mEU9Y8r@7k9@om//3Z/8a5qtEr0pe9SDuB0Bn2jU8tuRq6vh1dUNXNwtF6lHOFLZ7TiYede1FpkNxpRShrG1ncjqD@xySvjVtrV4xFMiooN@OxfxroWTni6Ak9@DTlZyHrMgsn9s5XTtwQ5mpxYsB2GzQV3TKwK3FJ68umYMPlrVdrdr6WRKpVjprcJ23io77C32QL9VNtirShUHTjVcROJ3s25Vq1WEwqLVRGoryvQcuNVuyvUEo25aaBO@NLfsrbN5hj7bYMWiDfamtyX6@M@2PGjcbdn0M7c8Dz79L3PrS4/JOAqRSrXbtFvIjslyVcj/rRSgcxZ/90u/ruv5v/uTX71uXDe@gKqhWCzmNT3yc@3nPwcPa9Yv@y0z6pHGhcZoCFp0bMVRp2oLGpN4/m2Hcf9@@w5bdAy0BqtrQ7Mdv6QLVIUoaxp8U5x2jLxt4fLGJCnWtGVFvCxJgQJKirPbbSUJBtvCzaahzEpX0kfoBDUrq4C0lD6agWJ4TH2/77QaXn/sDmmWc4zCafUkuwdBIIaPcBehDXGaPIlcBaRUaut2UI6yR1QjpYgNTM/DPYmgEpE@giCPge3pBCs2NHAFMfq0bJDxKnohPMmhXYO46xB3nwdokG2MUs89JBnHjgeyQbmWPgLFgKhggcLArB3wUAbB8hEQANIQE4CtOtthmTi7shKJ8mzDoxuc@8oPkRdLCiUMhtDauFrWD1xGf2AFSj0eUoF8IXIYtLOQpQ@Ew@CjkhVoFmBw@kKNi5YXvzcogEVbecQoaezevRlWlYrVjjNKEcI/t4bYOUX5YC/HFYD5DaqP2yU5yexEAjP7o3m2A4onCF3gOoXvIVUOBWUyft5IEvzfm2mRIxeyihzKmACRX7xUtIBkEBjJzvOwxXYqTNO34yxAvgW4twgp2ugoaCWeTT5W9S98xxvA8OcRf6NXCY@ND3X4Cb5dXL7KoDoc4y6buIkJFwZi2SnfpgSl2OHIDx2EgqRYffLdsVxow9CoqL/nUSyjxTHYbI8owoNms@pZhtNKc3F8USj0zeBt4O4@Ip4N6qVvOZCh3tCxaTsg2roAZ@wCR4CMEruqcLTH9iXuyizyhgKHMfJoRxXkfMSYtjeig64oLA4zNl1o6Pq0STKzq7LWoM30IosRo9HuL3YALk6BCOGmiRtxuU6zbw4ApRPTZLgjjldKpbqgFI2btAXOEwv4qndgQVVieylxpljq0jq3Uqe4q6TidECDFguKI6hHYfHjI5piu5m@45yzvnVu8n7c2NxybI/p@STorEmg7OwGwpawy1jPJFkanJPcF9zb8NrmxkIyFHYjNo3ffme0jVgDc/Sa6iTLxfPCLgw7RF@6riXRCvamnr@hA21LAN9qIHJNsZS7EsVVpMEeBZLYmqJCuyKo2Jc/jEGL09/SAY2gipsX4EPRJKxjQGi2/MXRWIohtR9RBUBlD0oW7u40cku4pB8wcduxFhQ9IeBt9jHL6BKd00L7bYi9MQAGZn1lHjq4QVBMhzdqQ8aofP0MyBUonYM2uOFSUsF@GN7nbjTTzlsz9mYbAhxWOhRXhfFi4X/kQh9YOpCfKekb4JgHDJdgshGTEwA2IcdlDjoIvxicc7tEsqTEbkNKMoQgSA1QSFXwDxRkoe2TJXB4aHh880CxD9Tl5aVKG5KNXUs1PdxS2MNTElPDrgU6sZMamYOhOLzFwuO8BNyZSeE7iePZmfcndGpl8d6UvyWp41XE/INYtONFsXK8wB1zuwPayAR3EPGIoQ4s2m27FRNTJjj/6fXklc9/JeQ/pRC9QSCMIZhJcppsJQFYstk6T3Yu22XhcEEFEoBDLpq@Je4B6PofA883WcNO4MMZ0fx4/7vZP285fQd1Epn3rs6i5in0fU79T/E9tCYQyDYv2a7rGtMYucfRNzJwbEpqD5tCtU8uYIRqhl3xHemsSW1anws@CYJDpRYMJ7u4S4l0tR4o354Q3SfcfQLuE@4@mUXqR1ub1LlKhlY3mBzketzcyveJYKa@nxu@ld/MhSCDYs00DgJ9TufsbuBuVSi0T2/@BflY8RkDeGIIBDdjqdrLs9pZ3fbMy616ItUFZpeJEJDjALpWJ5petgMzUr9/0R863pyVjXuaQa0k8EarVk9wA@cVTGOQQcQYnF4WbkPVHai8G4grBCLBAAH1MHBE1WB3FLPi5WCTS3IExqnJMxpzxGoCmTppX8JJ2IG6xEnPCRsGVA8BQvsgSYAmuDC/5PAN5H3p8MLFE3R9vwrteT3A7VCi9ShQcqGocFlTpkwKYaUoPppAdlRXK4tJ8d0hK2oLTqFk3oj8D6O/8cHod6BcLMeeGJZXGGUpXFRwQhaoEKK4EFVZtRLKV8AgtWX0TRdqrn2un4raGqLZSvnNDB4PJsG7xPPyYqHMb8V5/tCKJdmWSwErTCsVSOK0woslLxc@STnBg2CeCDb1GUGE5wIEYKSXBjNFsEk42KRS4YKDTVYEuwwhOSEkJzwI9z1ZgWRdBIPWU3DQKmZPHbRTnP4lAzyNV6OgBg1lhofm4ZD1l7hVEw5kijhnMoe4QPAQqtjIZ6360thrIaRDQmsBADLiLQBtfhZNSVoUeJoSfAUyipPSl1H8S7ABlxXAYCSCy3w7w1jAZNQGBoVfTlA9AGVXTtQkWcOpZ/RL81tO@pb@rd22TM/71OYt08mF3z@KZR0pGyqgIe1DS2dRIGNL5rk4XnhO54jgsW09B7S65qXDYkuUbbBP@ScTp5p9p5kaGDhNBE@oCM4rjvvtBxwRYQ@GzsgYOdlsiTeaLGK7ZfHzNoPVtR1omoS3MQVdr@2Ynh0dQaa2nK5teWYST0jmKrtJkxb4JstSWE8WRseTJNE3yZuxCJrzFaq6jQaemdVoxDyz34mXgpmj@Kkie0ajErZ/wRQKD@JJAD0axhw8@30Uvxsm7rgrgp1arfPY0VA4RiGSXQYyrAX6P7j2QINhnjNrOdLen6hKN0cx2vG65wycLmh9Y0@VMPQC@MMZbETIGA4JlyQzsElbCm27TKUk1koacRH0sw8Oyj7TY0Y8CK/PA5gjRpK5izRGyrpLomusjI4H8@M7@XB8T8L4nqzHl1rhizjzpnmFO35Y1JnYDAJ4nKGRuRsNTDrIrfYtdOZQCaxRr@IB3hvFNk3DaiOmu@B1V3hXO8AfyeDLg68A8c9X0X99BvrB9983@ww8SPBkCvJmgLMDY7TJuuePbcbA@2E8LkWWRBew9qP3jAv84jEQB6hCgBpLgsvGbQuhYA6h2e0Fm2n7gO/geZxNdYvvaYpVhTsuwcm9SLJzfXUWPWq0zb4xNdsx4TMZguun@BgabCSv3i/hKOhI6Dm8rReDuiseuEI1jkTnnkorWMZIXsTjq9mKe7EC7qGecsLwcDX90P2WaMYuvgrvrYZ2QDSKW2jZFxZ2fw6nwynfGbdP23f7cpTXPzwncV323QQBOoj9PJKzaOPrxOdxLEjSe9QIgV91Psm4caUPEfeEvJ2HH0aiu1MKmRsKVPFzWZrf5X15jlvrcjzEFT5P8nGj92PJu5juvXkuxGoc2EyE7X1YFXILMk7IaLViYYjcZm2OOfYtmYB21E9nr6hVGksEahCSJN3IouY26RdxCVvGh/DGDqfP4Y0Au@aowRnKTxv2aYlDKxi5DIxhSGsRNqCkA5QQFTnJBRohX5JvBu9XN0GcrZVxtm7F2ZqLMygB81GGPEmtuShFLmD2rMuCvtkZrZDO6IRtZ3itE9tw2Y7hYm/FVdSKlqwki15ESyCQo2a0tB8DoRxtR0uPyOBFSydkOI@WPgPDrGxFr6Mlv1igBxc@yfAA7YUIx@9WtLQXi99II@Pc9Px41WgpyFPwc59/EkWAFJhu0BpxiM12RDJHrgkVGymVSYYc4yWx@UT9MEm60/Dn5zbQ/u/oiH2cW@SZJZg2V2mEagweD1Qb/v7CS0pySdTm@0cHNKEp8ILRJKCNFw5D4EENj0TnhRFHDF1pRAPegCDKzdJyjFioJntPdETswKGUyfPxE/VU0gfaMXKvgef6LBI6rEOE9/NrHgTPwPfDEwOvwvMWOn50hBGOycaXoIVEfRVdkyjM63lcRO6Hc4j6uuc94UmcvheeSwQ2JNNBh6PBOYxs6AznmYRccYK8FQ5DnXK8UCL3LgQjqSBK5gpnshYpQ8EQLvzxdckJhUPU5kQQOtbSdV7KgnqBZDE6zWRdSFPlhQ9QCMkcKOFm65wOQnkkjOSPi5sk1RWrqiE/LI@SJNe8mITAKm4wMzZGPPag8bqP2858WPPVDznBvpYYAgiFDGLh8tX5AP3d4fq7r1D7RFiIYJlivbwqva1er61lFzDvz6K9nYHomGSP4kuVoyCGGcmhdRDSzNfx2i0VH6d8cCWfRxpAX9D2fbIFbYI76LbYtuCwUEtwL@Ytz3WwPNdXE@q2RtK/UH2lRcWYBBye8ADTWdLW48oTviyL0YX6t43@B2ewO5/B4cxDeJQAd4HkvJS7Y5tmuczKNohtboMiVSsxLshpuDTI5pkliHsaug2GbcHiqHH86Ojp429Apbu9vR0XdfR0hh@WWuxrDepxDpnmTwf1wZJmi57Esw1wsBu74@nU240zW74lS7iwBmXAgFh89hNlPC5kWUieL5RdCMf9higqYJ3PioExJ5VQ1TGwyrYEXUdAEHMU2zIEEF@9BXonqbUWp138Gw086bTRoOqr0cDJS42GqMUwa/wR8fjPIxupsefSSWv8CIpLie/nxB4dsRef7p6y00/32cHzvc/YN46esxe7T09xbfOz5w8fH@4xuPefnuwzaW52JB7Xgw1KoOsjs2XiWWm4O1eW7xS15wynXO7E9uLc/sQYsE@dlonDVDueMXjQ4x@qbY6qPNQ@NEen2Idp0ZFMA2uE8y3oPCFoxqJy06YFeDjdn4HfJrRpB9jmHThtq2OBXwnbvkPL9Px1YKxvQQ6CvPXXiia5koRHB9HUITrkC2dgXUJwA/zj2A2AMfj8KzpM1vJ4ALOtio2wZtcHU/B0//jJCcPV83tHTx8dnh4ePT1hB0fH8PnsG4dPPwF6Hp6cHh8@fI5O5PHJ0aPDg8O9XbLgCKRVhuvXvxx7o7UoqOidqNI6x5FvOjM4@Jrv9UYNnl0atBTRY9GxjdLHMvrWG7MdLUtjD9UXXP5IQwUstrl7/MnnUOcz8zWOcPpDwTT/QH7u0RFWm2m2Q7FBYalCeSuL4grVnqLFaTxiMGW4o71ZpqXqMTInmQ@cJvG0LZPJezhHBfu@@Yp2Kss@aIhoA2AjKH/CSoXRSRTRaHKHQFYhtlbfwZ35eGx8EqH4wKAP/KkmZYkoJubKIFBcrnBoY3@QVg4sgO/BQhfRjlzugWUCC@6BZbkFqqKHOHeE5YSP8ehojOKZ5bnFl4PhAQ0Ls@3A4qFBrdiCwInnG2WpwYKTfHB9f5/OG@G9PHQOmuG1LIuCeOQfz@Lo93nBMPkpUCAT@VAizW0DnzIImw4ONYhpb/wQRHQFbsB5QkZn5LFYJa6yU5wcZNoWP@ml2zdsPgVqNnWHeI8VcB@ZiphmawUnpNACkKFDDIinM83jEYR7JLRC833DQciHt2I0xBxJOqXMn4J2FwIPbyHwi4ABQMpcS6dFNRWtOEUwTkewcsxzgCOx3/Zt2D@wc3vcMucCiFlbsS@tN2/igsjJuXaSP0@RsIMsemO6oFbSUGbHcaGMk1ilMyVQCrZ6znBk8TyMzaeARpyomgPfWLFBbK8q1bnYkA6LMdqOHYq0CVy8ItYmMOX7xEocz8fOA/E1O2AQOB8qYT7vDtExmnhm7mzsLImDSJcmdr@AIkxj5dj5OR0RJlz/lGay4y3DM8oKleqjh2fK21dJPKiMiwV@NqA/6RBvYEyMC4oHjfPRhEUX9S5R0vwDZrxxE0OLOXhCWmIp94FBO7BnQbvuQaMcuPHpxrftcX3Moj1ZXl9XeCgFJZM4LtLrxWbSLclqfpRJClNnYgpISHYCsiDrY75NkmAG8voBroTBXCgDRWyUI9huXzi@RYgQP3XNcQckizhFT2R3AD/OqjSjYnaoKC5sCedH6mXsYSVRjadmE0pYiJwxX0QnfchaPB6alkL11S1wj9aDA/n9/uAKa7Hj1cMHQXu0FtoH4aYkVsPi1VII1vuDfbsGLK/cfiGwkPbkasC8krwNLeD0gDmTm5FgNu36GF/dyjsqewAG617sQQmAhmIb2zRE7e@DG@MB4mEwM4Xo5PTR/vExk3n7BMKC3MMmQ1uIQYS9wZ7NZttaNgk7NVCagsZyoDz5NnMz2vxrXWFeSrwVokLoIElBj0BYzI7P7VgTLvVEzUIqBM2@J4HoU24euytfBnk1AfgG2oCA7CzTQgmUliYzwisfywtPAhd0S3LdODyHn2ZY87obz6Zzp2FA4TlBRhdXlizPvxdcPy758XAFy3w9pgS3QZOG@gbaCScQ8RA8qup8Dq7JFj9LcZI9V7AjPu1w4ld6XsP@@zMUMRJXwrkuHBLrQjkWqHH9eNNXc2hCIlYDBs70FI58RjM4@CKebHbCGRqfVXqx@SoIlEw8rexBmCsgeP2mHByfHZvVk5VAIQ@XtU3CpuZjWcfeWQG7vNrTxzgXOr8oHhajAmm7NirlHyYqXkvMxeTTfGlifEeAnM/lMnfBXkyFH1z5@8Lmdcii/BwNhtC@n4H0ph517wPnHj5N@u4zBlhDOj613i8wCwFB1VlSp8ylnSqjMH6AC@8XAmRwT2o8AG4x1jibLOC2HDqvkcLQycutNISKcJBQXmpuUf9mfXQokO@Mb@PD4@OFDT3h1MEbnJX/xHE9c7YqL7TRSsgK17XO25mua5M3vp5pgFBitIxp7WI7Wm3HJ7zyVKEjjbeFU9IRq5P4tNuk39dAkVD3oopnPmLvXnmxe0/RyuGkHhw@3mdbtCNeZ64vUnbleEj2bFj2OgRIBlO/BFYftIbvY68EN@CQ9EECmWg1X4xoE78TN6IIaM01OglETAsVslVbzP2O1zJs3PUjKX/sMTl5DwJSL@z@0UF8Wc96ujwXHpDzhnYMQiVlRZUpKNhhhy5CmgfBcxPtQxUWrtTwZ0quOanbSGmFdL4oUers5Cg5qBXrya1WRWZQ@Rr2wBu7l@3zrtO76LA@G37ZnLSmb14zlsuyDMSl3@N7smr5Soq2ktyGZ4EV08S5AsH7tL/smcyYSnuo4sAym7XDyxssTgZqNJdwhcQCl7Ktgc@FuMRuVBnU8vWKXUmXBzW7XsZFfqNEZZTQEjG0uAe1KMgYPjJfG9WxTg33upr2BcNDI@mQL7E0hNHSELB5YriW83j36SdzvXGoAGAXmJjrTR3q/LzHj3A2G649UW3zMia6yZIMOVZCBUn6iFYFabiknfqTsTumbQFmkCtJ0Ga9CT2ncemjtDoejhxyEREpyFrs2rqWPvKXMaWpRwG81Ky6j84OwZn5ieHAELed8lnUisbVNQ3XTsZDIGoYksShfCbLuKYQERVruWp1yVNNo9VDJPCA02sKxnZ26LhTYDVPpV48nMphuLRgIl1HIw6AwGtIow0YBWnuHi37kCD5@K2hgdtQH9WI1snQBHmJNEV0wenf7IrWN1H4HSAAJ/xHXOdSRRen0LxAkeRrB6lzAbclm2/44zADLqvkmfIRJhZh8/gqM@A0U5xohNEKMoH9R5dITk4ruEQKFI2@biUj8B/n3okkNE4tvjykJWUpOVXx1Z8Fi4WCKX4w33OIFB/dSQ3s6YLm0RMTitWU7Zn9PiDNafHRjBxopPW9Iv7/t7in3Upj2fJ3@ikqYCKt0A0mGiNCgooJZ4zmAsbjUsNpocGeg8ChUeEkzrozP@YFZv7PI8yr3He4v@Yp7uyPqurqBhPPylr3@EO6u6p27dq1d33tj1rV9YdnWOeFRp7Tc3PpuVi6w@mMVJTLgQk@yrRlZkqlv0T57kUqypadq6skaPHiQE@3HViSRHmL38obOpNhK4gyl3VXMlfqhO1YQs5I@byg9znlaayMZnCdfsbpkr/XZM9rLGN538brx19LdpBPxrPS1iTBpc4g6L/hSUunIJulgJpCcHHsb2I7FkrpgymHE1jB4Tk/iW25FEFZLagRh2QmVd5@m3LkIuNNJokGezHOCdYCGTGoRHWuEuGm5LAI9VDyUwMEwURGE0pyy6rwTBaeGWAx11NVLXtBzgk4NC0p4iX0i/yK/5Swx5FT@dKLE58w5lNuPHs3xwlEg@7T1GIyxUcTdBfhj7JR35hForpnSYiLB4lD4xRY1@mzD3YXj8Gf6nHCHCjUSDFHd50iKR1lKCj2fagLMfHe@oe7Yr3zYI096vtTUcFthkdeWFbMwR3Dz4YY2IlC0YQ3o1EftY604LsjF2oZKGRtHdUtEURjZnesGlr2cP4sPkmHdCjkiCOEfIcGIlFCeNPD291RsYPhnGBoxROXYOJYlcGMDzRAZl6ssZu5L25C1prCbr9nIsE9x9KDlA5HXtt3LFijhbD6sbipXZZveZ6OfiMYYAymtC3L@stN0P519x3qc18V8i8KBslupTo477x4GTlYAZFUwloelrHrhZeWZeiG26wbziHArDjAif4T8KZ/6w8GvlWBGYMyhrBoDf3xrd9xLKvuayUwwkVWRs0k@mEPb8ZtPtyBRZcHzIhewmGW1WHAYfiL8zOri9ukK8taqLSKtM3Q1bdBBwmoPE66Q9QOk8ICwwQwPbDQtT8BoqzYIo4S6Z4lLrR2ucaDKKAGxjkxdBOaDIPhJGhDz9BJltUHUKwGiSobdBKYQH3tvofOwc4iBNA9JqKAQkCpkr6FgyWV5n8IByEbpnTsnuoZF0a/IckKiLs/DmD0jQhMvULFDNyhg5vvaw3RONpvnlTqVQHPH@tHn2p71T2xc0o6blSUU3xb8f7oAEYXrU1nrfkRfEhVGlAyRQlW5fBUVH/@WK82GuKoLmofPh7UABqAr1cOm7VqIytqh7sHx3ukfQcI4vCoKQ5qH2pNyNY8ylKtqpgVlRNH@@JDtb77Hl4rO7WDWvOUatyvNQ@xMtTqV8THSr1Z2z0@qNTFx@P6x6NGVWDDrL1aY/egUvtQ3XOgfqhTVD9VD5ui8b5ycJBo6NHJYbUuyEjAaOVOFbCs7MAWFmuidu7V6tXdJjYoetoF4gGCB1nR@FjdreFD9ecqNKdSP81KoI3qX44hEySKvcqHyjtonJX5DlWgX3aP61WMf4SUaBzvNJq15nGzKt4dHe0RrRvV@qfabrVRFNbBUYMIdtyoZgXeW0ZVAwygFqTD885xo0Z0qx02Yc44/oj2DjZ08gkQBrCsQNE9IjCaQWBrgUhH9VOEinSgDsiKk/dV@F5HmhK1KkgFtKjYbZrZoEIgYtNspjisvjuovase7lYx@QjBnNQaVRs6rNbADDU0yDgF1oFKj6nV2E@AFz8Cs1qKc7PUnaK2Lyp7n2qIucwNHNCoSW4hsu2@lzR3MGCucYgSDPHMwLs2D1a6859ufYw/OX8is/iMRkdM2j3aq8KMLINVpaKEY5h1NhOhlMw0mGl0IrzGQtZ0/MubXisYdIfoY6qL8cHHddjL4gUsNt4AcW5944YJeb5CBdLpVutTpQUb3UarZWcfUzKGxvdKyGPwb@WyZRsxND7uvPHgZ2uL6b4dI1T5uVR0kqEeKiAwJ1P/OZu@ede@LVy348ti6LyPgNXRUchqkytUpcDQSM6OeE1FVCWdTNB7INmBCmYUeKfdwnNStIykTMMQ/g2@Ri88ORgfYHTm4y7XxU0soRH87qtquBIKiUD/ZESCoEtVOqHv/9rL5M3qcM/v9IbDTsa2VRnKO4F9YC9jf6f4pd9LFM8lyxOypHaW0fRDte@mJYzWP0uSCdkvzphalsF/rQn92AobjvmAp6ZUFR1Wy0PLzHMujhZJWSFDW6B7BXUyrvk@VH6uneBuLr/2spj4/l5/Z9lCe0GMUwsT3hmVu6Cf9xecAQSMYnEASQIZIcN1jTLK3kRnvoOMV5iJrhugufrKp3kdSAIL2Ruvb9aJs/E4mJrYwzj8rl75sHO8vw9DJ2L7cnP91UbR0mG3fs7y7ynWQ4FeKerYCOZxWKdRkiElu7DwIUkxwm1H7E8M7LqYEWOtq06jjxjnQdttxC2ZcCDD5oZ4Z8sATfRSPtIhJSgAx1NL8etCyZQMkIk11cbWXHtTWuJ7sFYiHpDGLP0Z9doU/yFsLf5KxHWDJANJFqPwusC5sLugcS@1r0xFaXNDgXswi5NSfMxh3DQN6KiL7GfRu5beJG8bvRiyKSPKK3U7lQQkniaxEMquYsCS/ZHijMgDYIoeBl9@lvwGj6cywB2Fu/PCSWXSADLu65J4Th0dRstGn0nIF@USdNHz57qmbYGn/LZEimRPHifrwCCGNBAqF2hUWBIJwEUdRyRZJVnAvl22xRfmVAzegXCKkmPlO3DuouZIKEUVP0S@q6gUgmHpICdMtTtdh6WynOo4FoqcMTL9ED0I/p9IkwXwt2HHCdAjahlBAB9FSYLKtILtKxEluFOKBkO7EVHT/HQagbk3O@ZKN0xqb6bsXwMkkL0zUx9OKexhN7OAAMjkeLBhyq82SbvyYOv0NmXL4qgnGbSvRxkh5wo1VczBzW1cZGnZlVW6FXyxhc1nTUaFB1BUvOWN2yVJPWyZElt58SxMMThbxf9wV@gARAs8cekVW60mOSsvpUyNAzLUkjHhdHTEJFiW3j@otVsRRojM2NgvNV@KUAC6jPjMt5MuARkKNs@NR1ykmVg0KQoeRgTHbTJOPjJk3SUZYvZ9hPOsQ4cheE/I5A4niD5Dp1B9ETSReUaGIlhJZHUYxRnE4dZ2gLQ0rd5p7OlkEjlUY3884Fj1Pp9qqRwOB/iQGJru8o744M0A5f7jms0s5q40hlm0XcTK@FhClsc7UdrD4RiWjh62G3DMBjPbESfy0MEfhDdjGb8Q5rNgLE8k1KIfqsFlE@/eaZrhEO6EWhhM0Fuh4xB/UJOufbQQ5fAk09yGyADzKh4tq0PHYLpaEJntKGUbaEJhSYmI22JDfP3KuZigMmSoTxQMQr25IJtNqgf1Dlr87objX3HuxyXQoON3dGRSAySdBXIn1QYU47E94aaPhiGdaEBX4AmIpkSBD9K0oSrM0a8kO0m7plQUHRNjl1JL/ng9mkmVtRRUFDGurB2YbyMHnYlUWpOhQXWw0MLaOqGyaMN1/@BmjKKFxtXWInU@0EPKFi8iSs/U0hGfeNzUT6f4JA/5S89ClB74gjpuuQRFhHHNinrV@XGO8EObgpPAH3fMM1FYyXS8ER6/0dZnOCBeVEeHMuxf25uE/gx2AG03mLoEo5X5aXg1aO0O@14vGAYe7NMwhPuURzx8nNEjdlhvPLwL6bofSugYmTqz6Jnjy3AYNnzXesmiEZornPijjGmmMBnPKlccJoJOztEIMLp7kfh7lIyRpsu8XI8KWXH/U7LHK9jFB8u@KCwqzBp9BCAHuHLCgoJ9SCfkmGQ4nxbnMlx@K4OB46XICc9@wGIvhvFrIBGpYWIYK2TmzBLMRuDO7EGMzzrTbIdiEI4x0JK/5@OtNGGGPmc9vGsXRpE3aCmwJQqbeaMoa1GmGIcQH2YPk3vt1Z@MPSDwA@gXXizilkWMQENcV0VbCnm/IqOMAi5kHhjQGE0jMYxiQQ9moX4MaGuahBpPnj1EDbL8gUWRDLM3x5UokRnY@OANcpkWDDmtmY2TyrJYtiluBy5BKpNM/mGG9b9nP0vCj0pcPjnDgWlXQs4YSD9EqjZQCS/0TJjXmihzTOXvS8za2mN7LUHA0iKTM@Pi2kxKrVzIAyXg@RXVWsMxDMapBPWkqcdyOBmOlh9JvQfHjoWR2RbRum3b3zUEZmYrwWS50iHSlmb4OCtaSXwSTBOnGFmaAQ/h9pWeNZsniTgttVDeSq3Zd@jwEM0iuyk9qej@7rDs46R4ixa9aqLRIkW4Y5DSov5@1oKGtx4eQSRM3l61aMRo4ZDRmvGjASpBJk2lx1OIuE/inqBHByiH9XaAdmb/PEjUpJGcCnmqkmJBLpGeGLgdnTZhXBp10fgCw8TxClcPUnrBOc3OSJVXyF1ikGFMYIC4KvZz0TkUn@BGnZXgI7odoJtpobVQAUcieCqbFg466L8mGEXll4c70uKhNcsVLooMaaohwa6Ccn0LkvI3h9ez1pSgzJECRHwBKXSL5samq8e36kfbAvkAApemZGnpm89iY2yxCtjAPzOpNcU1cFSVLBmTqLggtGhoAFmAXUqv7/N2FVd/wZg5Hq0bpBjBBoI/Z/BnVZbAcN4beU1tLDLtzDCLLcnN0maLXJmLRAzF70h@KYq81KWNKwDwGWMoXyoABAxrStijUoBC75icF0NU9hEULBVQLOEjRUWN7DwXpCNRZYaX60aO/KIcr00YuYVAYGGxOE@ECKxZFmeJoMBEtxAXI8erxe2JcsCCWPE@Uxy6QvZKnIa655iA8EjY6hHlrCCyecnBlPhy3Y4lav6m1Nd5IzWfTAX6aAzPcoVk6mY@lhqrdm0tXjRWEuhhm7XGEoEUtomwHhV@7I9cU8yQ59om1NhkxFYZ0j57gFupO9y3Of8aim1yylZrDAXP9AxX268WX7ESC8r@7QDsQsb9L/54Y5VhqkJEXhVAYemUr0uG94O0YE3hTI@two2uCrSn4xOoLe2wKz419/djUV8vZ8rO6Nofr@fzeeThSzP2vTKtxpOkYOjGc7vdm37fHd39NP506dLQj/fa98PhltpA@9AjIBOhMxz3@GIIxAGyYu6c9GPFrf5Nt2vewIAKSuw76DXOKYMhCJp/Am3z8qlJ5z8EUs6vv2ADsX2/CC18dx6vMyUUpYWC0mgRfJtSyjMgD37oonm2VlQRMByXlTETTFt2qfwFJxC82IQ6i6IX218i6@TUe7/fH2bFCd4XjIECntwnC@zvmwXynAUVjOTcexNSONqs8G@DvuFWjFlMVkdwal5S10yosPAYGr/u96rTUSZ19jkFswo0eRWbuYrhqbMi1UvZMlb8I8AyHwLaj8p97Y0ybaJTMjPM9FKAoyfA6EUhu3DrE8ti05GYpNn3cyNRF6PrUKwGaLpNSwEVyp66l1ryQHZN3NT5tNBFGuYZhsQJQ648rgR6mv15o@LtpNt93KBItwBwx/7TB0RSAZAESvEDemIQ7X/JgVjvJ@KJ8PoG7@qYH3ewQAsLWNazdum3u0ylUhFLo9VVUanswEMuJyo7FbGHH3Z2xB687@D789La@nqRx9w9@wt83FEf78UOwKADztX21XgPXiGthG5jaKyNXbzklpayxaVWabtcDN2zyg569cPT3//9P//@H//lVuTL/@DLDr2cfdaZHMdxl9pflp7fF/H9bO9ieenybGl0sdwrIpf9g4KGD2uTnBdZjzrjSyvNs4DxlcxI1Tabgs/IokJd6nftjX@F0WVLpNuhm5ZfQ744isbYdNs3vvvoRnkJO3h150ByJw9IpAHoDE/joXfaPtrfwXwDlARc0AyUy7NqRZ3bYzQYnUErVdIyEA8tWW99dGmJAimgKy7MWLlgEPoDPAC/pSUvN8@yPPgNJi3Jv@7nD2FvZzgVK@cZsZIXK1mxkkrRT2HjNXy1l9wAnXM5G@wGUqkspESaBbQyFGFA6zzaPtBVOwlyW9YS3diDkFSUCsrMTnBZvfkjXxm@by3sWU/wykzBJySkY8Ii6S9Lg3voli@Q4z4V87ShhUJLbmKoMkOhovsXV0BeyHYAUc3XTJCtIVSJij5ySMYnV32RfW3RZUIEGMlaf7dPco8fYC5aGkiT59hWCm85Iut5/opzY5F9oQltTOH6IwRIn8K7yTw5Ei6nly028jZaSc1kJ2yzfZL52NRh5k@UaToX@jdhMAEbc5uEWxpItxZpx83aFZEKtHbFqCqVNP0WllHk@qY/CUbSW4FqR4H6omu7Z0nCHiVADIdD9m/NSxidE6hAUYlu4buyZqIzxKazJAykZzp0sO2w4sgggvs5A7L9NSHbtktOIoodmAcIKW3J1/WCfiiDroyJ2D1vfImXA3pduk9twmozOs7DS1ITGA@7GmmHIJPFeSTP0JT0aOz1rr2sSB8Om2NvVoNpC1Y@k7ZjQwsxAhMigcInq17UPIUwt0h2CVFEN4UMh/Dugv5M3o7GfZvSLifYpUoUZNQVFIIYOxEl/a@xvkrQMeLqP9AJJspzg7dWRsohlkZeNDSSkFKm1wyJ2ZzoWKoGU3a04KQsRlVLpuIFWegGJ9pr0vvCSN7HEAGy7pR0ApSeCBuvsX6cnXr@wItNTqO@pfz83aLgeRHlmW6iZGMkS118WoguvEOsYB35OR4EgucmFc3IepLJPDkP5W1uaXMeoRjf2hTf9USg75@j@8vIMUQcDwIeLBMzVHQFhiNqZPgPELp9rwf4ze68GbLieTrz5qlrn30@H1ysZM4HX89/twkTOSSrWTYn0lKXrUYsKSswM7rZ2KsySgtVpMHzQTzD@UCwC4tBAkDEzZx9di@@uoDQeRpvnT9PM0FiXYaYuN@uz0Xw7hya6TgWbtp6Yq/YqvMzbwq2gLmVfrEP@YPNv4CF2lTSKT3sc8ZdAEVuur/dsMdJ6G6u5V@uFV7CTqjnT3Nj/wbn21x4c@lPYSkR4nYWpp7z32PcECPE/TT0ivBxCu3kW03Y9SSUPkpyCJViTvVYmq2gjMM8AfmByhQtFT1cbJ3HQ90jmghmBbCcykuhoNhy0OC@DM6f4fAa6/FCHNeSziHMkWhkwCYidIKaQ8jq7pWHONRW4rJMbk6O2MXQrQQEutdNG7PFYDjIycWa7SwXcRGNTjP9zfxmPimjcyIak9AluZhafioK5Tev/vbfR7@lJ@nymnsyht9J@rf0xmaaH@EB3l6ot9t0Ob2N2Tbu0zMX9sDw@Opv/wvlyz8BHEyZbcO/8rqCtTFLl3MlKvI1Xd6Ah8LaGtT7f3/9K7RhiXdseBXrUisrCLGiosiuNyDehXRRw1bytnQ5GlbILwthsIEh7M3hBe2ipmubeTqlS0ujiltfBr5S5ihyiie7rAlZCvFJhjKngJURFyhhBTkGqSwousIw3VBWG8i8EZril2fORgg7gF@kNYeuUltuPAvRYmiJt0XQgRmuEfbz/FDOv0lp646tlDIpKaolJG7t5Fi7@aL4/w)

Command line: `cmake -P file`.

CMake has `#` line comments and `#[={N}[  ]={N}]` [block comments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-language.7.html#comments) (like in Lua, only introduced with `#` instead of `--`).
`#[[` turned out a bit easier and shorter than `#[=[`, so I use that.

Output commands:

- `message(1)` – prints `1` to stderr
- `message(STATUS 1)` – prints `-- 1` to stdout
- `exec_program("echo 1")` – prints `running echo 1 2>&1⏎1` to stdout, deprecated since 3.0
- `execute_process(COMMAND echo 1)` – prints `1` to stdout, works as needed

CMake requires a newline between `]]` and `execute_process`.

`COMMAND` has `CO`, which breaks ALGOL. To fix it I switch to `COMMENT` before CMake code. Another option is to hide CMake code between `#` and reopen `CO` comment
afterwards, but it is only 1 byte shorter taking LMBM and Prelude into account and requires 3 lines for CMake instead of 2, so I use `COMMENT`.

CMake code:

```
...CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
```

Answer (score 2):

## 297. [Onyx](https://github.com/canonware/onyx), 13850 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@              (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                                  @[[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::   _@_/ 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*[(*)]v_>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_>>>> [>]R 10G|'53'S 1xxxxxxxxxx      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v] >>>>>>>>                     [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #  ????!?!??!??!!!   !???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*__+++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+; ;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++'4o'6o@<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM    @,,,"286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRtMbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ '`e```.1.0.6i_]56pq[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__DATA__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM\// >+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;W\W/WWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  (((((((( \'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦→ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
1     ! !
2   !    !
1+    +!!
1#  *
53  +
#  
1+  *        +
51  +
#  
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pppppppppppppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa













































































































































































































































































































































<script> onload=function   (){d=document;f=[].sort;d.body.style.display='block';d.body.innerHTML=/a/.__proto__=='//'?275:!/r/.test  (f  )?267:!/\n/.test(f)?257:!/^\n/.test(f)?259:d.documentMode?262:265}</script>
<style>body{display:none}html:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}@media \0 all{html:after{content:"266"}}@media screen and  (min-width:0\0){html:after{content:"260"}}</style>
<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;min;dnu&&1Prers>80::\0}ngt=Be;bk:pextsepsEx Cr u Uitharbodyh$/+--- $5"6c"2:1*F 4, _._#a*een gi=[ Show]pR 8uiogr ca34* 16  prstdFloat
在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...  ){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1?(1&*z(N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};instance Num B where fromInteger _=B 170;negate _=B$ x#x
>data B=B{u::Int};e=error"#"; f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e )$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b  );instance Num();instance Show  (Q a)where{show _=""};f=(^);q _=r$ (d.B )?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h b=b^x;r=pure ;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z| (∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=[246,264,0,263,261,232,222,209,210,128,206,207,214,211,212,217]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,  (0`id`),k(0::Float),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l(do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h (0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!  )=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[0!61,{-_-}last$172:[u$[-1]!!0|g<">"] ]--} 
 
#1""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'

#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4@cLzI1KgbpEUCZAAH@JDZJVKJd2rvlWlakl163ZTLBZIgiSuSIAFkBJZkiq6e3Z73WPvrLenx9F@jG@7ZzxrrydivBM76/aOPRNhf51wzCf/gPJjY8Ox4f4HveecTIAgRVJVbTtiPyxIAIl8nDx58uTJk@@m4fV@9rMIXuyZ0592@86IjUxvxNqudWG6Kns4ZQ8My8vpGUlCX7tudzww7ZFXkiJMY8wbGe6I9Q27Oza6JouArc5m3x2rPzLdJPNMkzXNvnMJ7hnGbPOSHdotqw2Q2Mg5N23rjemCW5axR2b/enA9Yi1nMDDstseGrmWPyDXH2DMDPjrj1jkzmt7INVojy7HBKc/Yc7tvDJptg5H3oWvyQNsMQLXOKcy8S4GxJ47rmRCD0zI9z0HLIlgaruU83n36yYJ/Lc0@MQCpYd@cLESvaeyFZbrtxRA6@/z04GDRNsM@UxybHdxGScuy3fHIORwtws@x3a5pG0xXi6q@6JgHYo7MfiFdSM85gduB5UJuGiLXSrOcsceDpukC8UUWXlqjngoBTh1OcObY/SkzJwAMcOyAN3PELMwtlkun0Sf8T8yWY7dn4MHKBDgA1xwMR1OmMNsRPABOjsu8odEylbbZtwbWyGyzvgXYOR2Bjccgw9m5Ob10XMh4hbMiIeINzZbVsTCISIEnIbM9MpvjLnPGo@EY0PNY2/KMZh@8NaesbXaMcX@UZE1wA@KR/WXPtAVKlt3FdLyY2SAEG4oAx35TA9pY/T4DdM4RHYzaYzvocIn26LVpEpZmG0Htz8gFkIy@56d@PuK5aDDcM9fpusYAGLVtEg0@P3zGvJbjwhfc6JeXgnVgWsaI7eyw6P7TR1FWDciouk0pIGmFXTHGIr4juzD6Y9NjA2MKcdsjKFzMofzzQ0jgnUU3oiUWzWSYnmbZLMtCYSswPZdmUCSKYIBSq2c0uPNML7CsBnyfiyYxno5rdK2@yaF0nX4HAW0jx@o5psMznY0muWuL4thmmQLLb7PtHNuGZ5EVdYgEIWaZVszBnYcbIBQBAw3uTJbHFLAFshMkge2xjjGw@lMOfThE8C2W09g2QAQ0NYCsFwBCUUcI81cY3qgHhO0ZFwBS6VvnKC7MQGJgbqXgldraSpHIQtnIo/R6Zr@PsQKhgES5AtuGWPOQ6CzEDHTUC7qf@G6Pkk94bafhBhy3IcUFIG8aKJVGUm3DDd8ghnSQNzoIFx3kha6BvQ7mDEIFf3lwy0Ne5QPS6m2iLUhXCKshMVGgaEgDCMYg6zJZBpmXhezNYPbmMgzwBAS28wxkSkFjhSwrbDMgVzHNgPQaIIN5r4Es0wAJDYFBlmqQpxogogGzaABUy@SYFKKrlkF3CJuBsEACLQthsmCGfNHyeEM4yHgNotQgTl0vzlgLcNNzkMhchnhOz0PmbYMbEEsHXHXgFh2w1QvgjmELQLgCsuS2TwijP@wZSAvIAWRkYDUgSA5wItjgH8z6doazFPlumiOrJd1IUKp4DRiWOL70QAkA0oQZDCtQYMAZ98QCCRgHgTQvrMae2QcuAhnSMsCMbAulHSWHD8caqShnoZoynQusSKn4z0XjkYhouliLgrxqm67L0C9Utl6ShIk3bnrm6zHWtTO8OiCdTBCsHcPqBwhQ0TFGVA/AO@pBfNN5tDuuM6DyNUBh0Xec4QqxC6LpEgF96lyaM9RnkssYDvsgz8HeBEKMjT4gc2mQPkDqQjhWjhAEwnCtngUAKSqQq5Zrtoj2IukQOgMSeB7FEtOr9zII5WGoWsiwoQNC1cMw9rjfL0F1Z7ZYpppqmxcptOFVx3yVgTj4lQnUhwJE04C6nCpTxCKAdE9XqZo69XPWcwbzSePi5TBIes/CKqB/aUwh9zogWcyJMQCNg2G1bkPFPQCO4TmIOeHxiueQtR07OgqgXLpQvUKig5QAyD7RZGQNTNDHHAiCOZ4lpFG4EWbNKbAyUSurkjrGMVkglCotEopbZEMWvLBAxdYet5BqGLdlEwdBheBRbVUFuFzpVNEARc41jTb3htoFYhTSj6C2M4HoQhVoESDUUEzbA23HU5mFaiEwfNfpAI9RFQ2qBgSdxdOitGPKA6uJ2lIlojTyzeC8zyzWGg4Z2IN@AmgdpAtQxzpfWuwNOPZ7Huu3xq47ZZMhZIA1AF@jltPpANO@MYc9AMEGbdaatqBUQiqRaaS2QxKoNVxIcvC1aYIf24Rk7z37BuuaQG2okTuAKXH6LAHDISWBSGHYvLa2DaAUJqE1nBJZAEwQouM4Ktq3HdMjHgFtJijxGJlndqlEQPHqzGTQALUPYE7QCGxgWRA4olQhfIxQWpoYjEpk/iemDSWmBcwIZR2yD/XRXdYB3T9UWaNyZ7Ra5nAk2MMhKWbZIYXm6AAVGrJVBDDV60mbD0AXm8NAAq@SzzmhGtw4J@GKij7pWQaKWNHAgDrdNgMVlnGB0p/eih58XCzELr9CP3MYvJJX4DCkkoDaHcmG8QglCApFq9VDEThCIUNaBhQyd3w7@WAXjt4dMKUTxI3YaCBtJDUVWCEeq2EocPdvA1KHfYRVnbNAr3MWd4A2vMESyE6AZL8dtlVThgqy8C6gA8d2lkAFYgZw0cu8C@UFMeMJSg2jHzAjFRdvLo9QTs/avlh/QdU5HDoulAwudKYoyXiWhbjL4e2UWFBFxKHdPF@jQk0RxXp@NOJtrmEf2kFUxLCkgj5pgKQAIcZbACDzHB5jCGEq9QRL4HdJEp8zE1Shtm2iSmq4Uw4Ekge1MkQ0ZZbrghi8wLqBVz1@HaISn0JVYLTbKFmRHFTuFyNXkaP3xk1rstjMaKGl@qUnXRgu62ALwwVdAwpRLNrxovEy2VPIkJOccoajFAXlTxk8kicVsjzWgUYLVAQHIGhOpnYrJs8VMTnJ5PGoU5DjYMCAXDVjXzOGo0XsvgQ7ZJrBOZRr@iqzLtTaigJPBe0IE3RIqehguKBeQCEELbtYbDcNdg3Sw2XKZI9Co1pIb03NBnGZdjuISxACcQmnV@VReG6LDEqoVsMUoHdKOVUScwR8T0pQQBksUilRf6IFKXncjdQZbjm2qXuAxbgGEmdXgYoOFUCMkLFA57Ba1qghtJR793x9ZaNSAWYDJQrEZjseVu79fhQVJDV4VkkJEZGoI@dkhGUjFof0oucbjg1oS8CplSq7GvVcKHH0fSOBJyCrZCMn@4QV@fzUOh@3FzPaRkv0JGOpA13Jao3ksgSVPy8NlXVUjc5RFZT/KFIVmRfDE@hbzEu2mKGy8OaaHmq9FYFKKIdjiIHg1aUk4kGF3Yyh96atvlAJuAkKO5dGTUD/XLTUA0GUFDqBX2hvlVQOBIsDh8Oe7Z5@WhFlkTummpZdmrPoOy2jT9ab6F32wz4@fHi8e/yNxhIYfatZWrRIWdlCHqva8UTp2uNUVtVLm2EYM8CPGuthY8B5P7IknJniTEKq0rQFlcvEJ@fR8WeLJAFNCMlBMYAZ7wWVhvsBpUtqGl5voRJm3UQCogyC@H6Zcsh8mIEBUUd3w8fn2fjNG8y8RaSGwh4x648NDsC3TB3afjgVHRcUMN@p2eE1IoUFLdSysf9zZgr79PH5BLXmRWRIlQ6xzCdHB/vHFQLbM7xzs99XyEvKG4EuZbhtFXi@P26b0jI/IP7A1GIJdYY46tOE61ICt1pzBJ7lLVsBHwBgE0d1mNIf@EnzeoD73mLayFZpBRxA3wRhUa8M60OtD0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhVlkFVktrrMB1vtpq5XLmdrYYrrZaszjbYaADUootx9cbXXA69xS0UWdapFCrBfonj28h7pESCU0BxcfM6zOV4vL6ErZeFItFvdQetNCcvqm@IIknMzmeSkX9jk@15VGbM@R/f2KNYuk4f2tx8Aux7@4e6o98z6KjjjowqNGATXCsmdwODjS0POAR2@k7XYdtQRiuHfoRgtq0Mpm7Xce@lUMGWmJSIzhyAfIX@2uMIdQ11htqOFKocHOVj3oYtncJUlrLZ5BIRCEClSL/6pfGhQHkmqX75PCb@1CJaLl0OjCn6QIShMIQudDUCtmSBVMgIlXgszSBwSjGrdLuOyihYQRMtBB0QcDdmfNSS5KYamqp/yUo8aGlkB9UqFEdt5yoR/1wKLOwA8QbQqVN/UctzAEP2/4j4HzeU8M7GUagT2MGQLMqil1jhsc7ICCQGFDww4MeFkCgjragk8kOBlIgZygUqd7QJAfVG3tCerMeBFTogeMgQsIJGxYgHWzqEOyCwIXAPCG7PCE8JrKZT9I5NDlshNY0WUFpWiPef@eMXeyot9rhtIH3jM79ADRKXCjPqEcf2vi8B4UHplSAgmeA@g9KPjQTQHJSn5RJSTD4aADqeR52QkHTJa1gpyjAV9iDvZ5ht0zeFlQGqCAxZbjPoiM3tat8M2Uob4BB18hNTPxueHCKMv3UJwD1MgSjU9QCEr0bJHmcAXl6QW0pdHzoV2XScDrqQYqVFpONijM07UV9jmt7sXiZxlCiUfVLx7JjV9GNjY1oKVqNJsF0H0w7aLqPpgSY7pNJIRP6U9FEIZJkQtcahUC7evSm5kOexOvIAxOUCm@sYcyolUqZetKoaeKt4zsOWQGUB98KvgBONF6poDEel6uX2A0LdXMo7XvIOyct1xoKEnwNCjv/FjTIEBFAdcea2jXLqHeup8ig4oJCaGL1EXOjZ7X0Wf3s6qydOLuJJjF0vGxUQPeLQXyxgdp1nfEQhHItW1K0ejxey5Tq5WYlmo5uxWIFpQ8RGfH4x4V4wuC0jkWh1dmPnZ1FgaSCOrVWzyV4k6QejweEAjygRdGGuikWVa8KEH8zXo8nohA2Hk1CW6ASjQJdWkgEjxKN2j5nogNoXHrYyQwt1nB/IQlz6m/G4vpNc9ibumEPQYsaalDsHZsNtEFhoKHKcMX2hocPC@s5Ld6v07g/qLiwYY6ycDjl0lrimJ6l5gZ9/VrhQukMnJGR@lwFhSiIRPZS0Y1oSlFSMiMXDomS/cTysAgbtumMvXAvwtLODYwdbE97YxCW/oh4ErjKGkpmq@ew6OYDgM6CLlysELA3WuF92j6AdkuFG4Xo6eERw45Q0x7RULEFchGHkXmLSyMkuOjx@91y@eFrNYitTGFYGiOyurbjmgqQBEJINLBL0wCkKhOjxYfUqr3V5yhc9yBKUqotEyTiQd8xiLZcXIf6eoeDUHjQvSHIsdmW@iA/OiAeVZ4XrtlObUk08OK4PaghIDUoifUgtwbCIeV4w7Y6mkBQKQZKz5wj19xArbxkbV3X861cp@S7IVcAsXuQSahx2qC@@k6KBo5xkcn7vMnn699Pjx7t83ZRauy51LLCNnJj4LTHfeBgrhMdm3Y3yfaBnyzbGVhABj/8m/P@seOMuAYPH6taXVwhtgbjvkHtucUm19pwLafp9KmZty7ozP/Y9Yy@wRuYvuvu508Onz57fnpSUUshTynjYrA2buxjWB4tp@dheDyBhlD8rl@PM6a8mZOx3vInmqCYEQ55dBiLaSaQR779Ntr7RQr7R4V9Ae0HOMUEWg2ihUCfgaXwWCSPOO0ER@uF5ZWWvkH7lfpV4E8jf5c4ASWE7ZWmk/3FqNOZs86Q9bmCoqk/s86SNZ9@Mqf/hVHKcU84F2XOTxhQnvwEU1IW/QnhFQwf9sy@PzpwDIoJ9oBD3d5H9ck2L7F3ns8LMb0W6ttjmyQ0dp@zVs9wvVtNEihTQ4X7liIbVE6gDkuh5iJtppjovipTSYEmAR928Lj0dEBtp5bRTpUPRgFjWC4f9EjxjrXNBoDYqZb9mQKrvGFM0WjgjaASbhCCkklDcreSGgywetRfJlGQsuSlai/PJnpaOZts79dTHhGhw@Szs8nHaf0LOclwPsfmvVTXLGN0K6lF37yPqdUDscESk3mSQT6M7Y7Tbyu8QxvyHzCmHmsvGEYMZpSQwAcby/Unk1g4QC0m/YC4DM1DuQV3Ieuqtz2EZq4EgKA0XLHr8@TFNatBDXahesO@NaqzG3XkNHqY@NHYtRfnuHCV0nWNqSeJUegK2z3@5PNaus4hSAMDO6kLPLcm/hQp0INB78GZaGDCsfSRNaKKnQYNLUyvpgJSE@rPBPQBBo@gzIKIRIoQ9WvzepaWjjkC1ctEzL3pIMnM@I3a6RujkWlz3uIjBavJzbt0RTQViv6@6B8ssTR1ooKiaaEboFhmJ6eP9o@PVeBQLxbdx87WEhQ7o9UDfWNVon1KhhNfYh@3o@xjDBNnGAsUKWhMNER4YN4yMDc0JyB2FAVd042BZRz7SVtgTV3TFJArXIJAOCOiNSIaBcBiZhzSRMBKS/F/bvOWk8CzxKIsQZQEcsfulYC2Vlwd29Zr1YN6g9RQ8BLlbU@a/lbZjJH42tTixD@uNcBxHmgykRYIaajV2AZIN/Its8pb9rKWVor1xCar18t89A4Cok5P0@nE1CxD0JN3dZOAFDgfilZZZ2GCnh8D9cpgKI6fBjwrCb4FZN1xc3q7lMqbuhwPkFXegAV3lBeRXDKBjKPoT1sgEUKzHOZnK8zPhQgl6zk1shcmfkJyfASC9OAQQ4ynkm1UmBaP@5hxQC8MF5vOJfbM8Tyr2aeZaZ2@xWd5BJV1SRBGQPIpE46ujAWD6IblGcoZZsZsOiKf5CcoQe5U0UBLClNGFrE4u0JiEil1pCK7vkYLmW3qjNhAxtmAnL43fpsW5ONjB5B9LGY3hnUOEhpi6BlFx5kk@423@bEddOENg9TFgs6rXMjhcFzntOxzh3qIA1MjrWo51DOD0IPz/u2QHcvr0WPOa4AD96uvws4bNDv0WOKBOkrFEBxZUBec0LAhO43UMb2oN25JzPPDznPRNs3O2O7SeAWamfL6Dp9KsUCeO82mtcorEAFnkvjvJd5AVmLJ09WsqvmlBzt4oFoE@cnbRLOkL85YYHN0h0pqBKHE@79@qw30v507PaivsGczMDRAU8CcUjorM0sExQ96LM9YPvI57lsGEYZMd4FsGS4kyegHhuWgadhOUUDfGGAnpMhx4E18gC66hs045nwMwX8vj2RZN7wNcru1yu/CDA4eFXUYQ3OxTUTgOpdlUiASsjwTzAnvtA013FHg3o2UP82CETPzfO@NR2P@BHX4zky0hnivK5vCZzpnNDUTGqRG0zLXZLlrnI/bjjI87wZqcX6J31nqadRIAa1EDCA10Lg8@TyBrtWF6t5/r/I2q19Tl/S6iys8e@wNlSa17dv8iwrCYE0Mbp8/V3mxxCqEwLCaalafHu/JiQI6MIoYP03h7DQlRDRrgcx9ozlFVaj34VwWjEWCxKm0Eol0ZsVg1HC4Ojy2Tyl8sbg89ERtcXos63lI8RlwCu@bowSLOXF35CpUV9bA6Ct6O2RcKcyXDWXe8hqMglAY8wIyjR7rmBwrpNa4b7gz0xoWn@HhD06s6ucW1YYoyy2nb3lYoPurpKY/n2YWF85BpEdozNRaRsk2NESxHlcC03Ip4LRGOM9sBVu9h0zj87twFl2IT1RnFbFaziXeKzWIHjSG@XN5pfZmKVbvIZ@UfqtvQFW@skaY63XEXs07ePXS8kx6LCfs@VJER63@Uvv5UuD3J4b7B@/ibM/qOx47oec6AnVdoAJ/LufpMC0tw1aolz1sXiOG/IHRWYYa/a7Tzxe6KQMeK3N97HZQ9Iv3@wq5QEhp2h1CyteAHFsT75Wi/Tzlnt@VQbS2w8VJcSHjmlp2maQSgzqrUwdtAxwRXJ6yg3SBQqop3oe4ImIcy7k0pv7756g9VpHWrz2GU9KoQcHDAMUCGEYu17J/ntiy62Nrv59QugV2@65EhDL3vG9CfUXPW1nK9LT2gSG0dPr9RVSnPzbH5tK2xlHzSxOXCK5pZ7w/UmmRjE0xBICjDjifPfD1RjQO3wtrrKrxa60wMaDVbt6tzcwLtSEo4ENsPT8DwzM03A7RtcfDuVyda6DZx@tJ1hv6Rdppz2GHLh8qhwp3KEtzKrpn0r220cQbeTirpJJNp9NChwkN5cx9rGtMZYKwX1r8ORcx2cxinvnF4Ts3ZFweB5ElPG9ppQjSV7XtyXOxmLIt2xxN8fme0rTpOP0PySkQqm0LtTFQLml@3rocu6XuiJnnbNZ74WGfR7Ozqt@C1zaieQn0wXbzukwPjzW9V24qOJo6wJGu@c/1PTihkau7YsGlmtgtxGfs9VfrkqJDRFML6vbaUsc1VKdp9g3@muSz6@AV1cxaePNCQ4wC46gxHyuejfFHFoTScArEstrQUOmZA5M@1yj6RvvLsee/VnqaOHivcp6YZis12TdbqzwMLZALNj7nBqdDytLIsaGJNTLcrolNlT5OPxO2qySwP5y4lMiHA6Nr8vXn6yTlrM8Cp@nwlt3MuLz3osSn5rQg2KyHeTVLQKE6N6ee/14K8Mm0Bfk6Htzd47ZQ@FvYDfoepX3VvLfbVazdc3p2z@zxyabB16rCAfw44vsFrEMdsO72WoxEU3hebJiefafffx96omjkgtJxOktx2scVc7jc44PgTo0mOIjXnf13xojLDjSsLDU9cwz1kueMnKGp0Ncqr33s6@HPVTLUH/3@eTuR1jb1gSL@@@eFf2fbsms4o@GQXo1hf@zRg4IqtNDxLr2pw@e8INmZ43bVN86gqQpLVUyIoUH35SKmaY1aPVxgyjnb7DrNVs@6C@mmaYxs6zzl9/rwz/dquyJlLKY8Qmu1bwF53amK/FIJu5/g63BVposOJF6tBYY1@sqyTjpay6kMjfOWxztE0cRK2CccKo18xWeJlsqWXo@t0QxoaJJU0MPLRybQsAp3MS1jpWZFE6tnYlhM11jJpaSko0KumGlQeLSV/UtzE@hCRSyT4Y9VCIVTSRiFJrx8CLnFpCLqILRCXbdgP8dfc7OhllZydm/c9W4LTN5j3wYVDR9LReBuF7eJwaV7DvP6ziVNVaPV0bP1f6H@bKjNDFu8VmWA3k/hmil4N0AbG5trB1xya0dcyJ/WVwzHglcDXpCp45W9a31r6PEnUzorx@nE9ClopS8OJnKqTZc3s0WWtc0OHx9B013K48ChEVzQTpQWjvZj9zqKea6ScZFmO10Q90qfzTz7flcpNEtnJi1njKA2Vb54anYNnN792Brh/NAl/ELMvGxG052wvz42POvrY0jZKjbEBeB8jNINrxTGryXwnhhdq/XpXEYESAoCi8ml/DVXMNDqdl5c9iwPZ1cFhjVdVshynImR6xrQoljic7FTP1j7Piv1fFXVUt/LOt6d4RQXn0zJtK7P3RpR/6t4r2pUrpp3thaJy/FgOPbEazkONH8r3D89OCd779IC4MprELqsZ/RHy/uwQ52xoJ@J6nJmXKWnf9PqO132zUKagToH6hmq7UsY5yFU3M9w0pBrL@FEivs9x0SxC0Thss97DXlrZphi2dZofT/PaIQTiPw3JobXKbgoIvUYn@qDD4WgnC6nyOO7WwGzlY531PzAeSfO2G2ZaAy2Lwg3GESs5p4/4VnUGrZ5GW6/rR3XgYrSsccjxR3ba2uF/NpaocQmhXyIDVjs6/tPnsfD3EATxO/ST01oFo69/nRmWjmbYIHJLBtUtNVydN6338p4xHdbOabZyXeE2cUtYVokrh85y1pCz6auOXrvphQI//HgkdnCMcU7437qPHFsB2qjIQjKwbHJlxDPzQJZHhCDPcZFskCf9p3RnBDYFZUQ1zaModmE/O3PTO9TF3HAj4yRsaIqol5DahkGpjt5xeo3TfdL6g4MmVc1ducR@tScUKtjNcPwMqiMWi2uLGNP3VwZmRvL8YaOY/MnSds0vLQn66UKVAX0eP9RdBXn/s/1GCxtuc0n9eiCTyEx23yN@6q0umbT6fPnmglLtsUnDBiuZXqpx7hkmuzyWaaA9uWtlSHba2XIrNEEmuyF4dEI/vJGyAykNvmA@UE9w205OEYmDGum7oTWOd8hpoPlBHxWQRMIPwGJZbTGYse1u9DqD5oDeqxsSoRy89hs4kKkJm0OMDImtzOT9xmJldGh6V7BemJfXGGhzrPYM2inxO@utuZaWPNUtYb0IEm9ciCdZvIotmW23hjYn@YQvWa91nPukObUUzKu6MUOFSPqX04ZtHB2aUman9cGCk3fVEY91wTld7Su49vftWHJSMl4YOLw8/z4zErV1fF6lFhn@Uh7IFxdUxE7hoEsCXYP4/qhsrtS80Tw8D96@LUUVMKNfNbfyQBE191j@4D82LXF63048JnjjTrW5AjwxhUJq8QJJisHQeDFSwaatlYlAnLPHvd5v0Q3NClr0KbmmEK7VipKn8T1yFRM@0KhfaUmt1Pk8HVmqV3cAnFkthWxrBrHIJTH/pKzwJt4LxlaDctGnAmqpThhJ/msmBu6jLiXvmQAfcsZKUOP3qmh9@zw8dGpOvS05a3@Hq7UuKXHza3T1gvpUGfVl4YbGgnlc9XaljdKPTzRlL3Hhyp6WEFvPtahwAvH7OZeK3tExYaDRspY2QpCV3O0XEH89PTJ48RsVSiL7fVcZ2DGw857JydJXPXytZOlzuHQB1A6Os5kZfDDfU2LL2Hf5zaNG66SnktiWgXp1ITWKDDjp3ybhzuVq5YzNNun06H5OVSeKMG994w@vzKRT40Lq4ulkBVXEooKKiuq@Ww8NG0bGtumG7xX5ee5NURp2aJXir9WTlRBzSGTcjPLtYd1cwEWtRiWFnMUPiyQlr7NrSNLgZLR7aEpZXh/X8Q0TVtF5xOjA/nKcisza97DspHjvnPxHoPMpmi8KIGVMgKuUqw7J5lvKwMQ3Sl8YMe9sARjc@UEmXUAAuv80gJ/adpTw1ZolGudelGC0Djdba2Xb5rvMVQVzP25wG1gl47@BfPtWaxFxvgdEZ@6oSB7ew8P7wpwLGi53tcnT5@zZ4bXMvp3eAxjbL4HxjPN6EsF@61wQ62VA61tF0Dpa@F1h8vLc4mdGG7bsaeTu4fnaNkrVu20RWkAC7/Ik9m3JtayuqrF@7WeLZ@AdEfcfL3L8dgO767oJcUaer5MjS8c8lR/C8xYzEgk4vH5XZbDy6T4AiED99mmtT3g9/qabYglPOAQrGoSC4dw52rQGkxcbif5IGps80ossymVtBtcaiSXZCaWQQXblvGttyqbMdw0CFBlyrmG@8yzTX@NDqO9Y9k1I@0BxJWWS8OXmgovmiyLxUusBNE@O3y2f3K6e/r8pJau38hxsUSPo2YYEJm/ePPjTFuGFAliQKXO9@GjRX59iI72tUWtw/OTxSBhCymrzKVslib5PobZvDKMVIrWqqWUG8BPkXls5AoiBq04bD/FRHWx1LDEl3j1iaLyJgctU5yQEyWWXhbx0PA8SJZwX9xZm1xZJoOuPGKxdRowWtdx2iJGz2R3X36MB7uHj58f7zMfwRkrXFrtUa9SzPGd9bDkKibkU8eiYe8Ki4ogUcirSiV6EAXCRNUoK9EKQdrVDrgXvPnUwbWFIvQWi20SfKBgNMiU1H/9VuomquIMrjj4jfpIRZmgPHpgp7jq589@t813ffXX@vvbx7sD0phpTbUkVvStWM@HFKXiNly9iTztskpL94LtXWcb80u06S9w5SUqUotbuMRpVwV@IoDYYcePiBjE3ykSG/y4Ww60Vi4sXLfHcejg5jXzrIyjhwzXOqtsF3fIB54H1kckAPWxPeIbRIjl5BHgIzUQE0m2ScjyfYrlkMfozgawctPsWjbzbNCizFGJfQl8ho3qEl88qijV6K0gPmh@NILSGw36IY@3drvxUmej1Ltf@V6qW2ZgnqQfwtcvia8OmH@Zm1@mMK9v74gziz@MhImljmPNIw9ojvQOHQZg80W6M2Lhxj2@/GPWALLmgiiN3nkM/KnYTJ7BidU@h4wCFoNcEotzeXymW4/1RqNhKZVCNsIBCpUmJJoTPjtABSZPvR7jfueO7aXyuXxWSwGSyoUPkPa27OLKJw4wHi8B40sX1rDyqgnstbPDZKyUzUq@zHMztWm8zMivAkQ3wa902UPkagzCQJBZCHCrimBQSSS0OAZFeRTVoiiK2g7UHuSOtQx@24IQMosBsTiNTNwscYKnQozcKXbcjPtt3HXJdkL7Hm8KQIoGVRCZ4rIk1pM@dUbAMnMrafl6Upwdw2sqHEv2@KkntEU78qB6uzTNlkH5GyyL8qViueegMunFSi@ct/ILBHGCIEryMpatvWRnozO7nuK8yYBNfyRYNszMNpj/Waq7gmd5undv78UVW9xJC4nFHpzYDmofB5AYFtNTeial5eOzJGWzS5MkUiSigeTgDgHXEB2IJhATLdP60hl6u3v7h187enZya78p8hld9AaSvLqTOFPUZK0eGKLhZM1nycOD1MmThwd@RsyQzockMOgkIiXaupTMGhUIcjZ9dTFpyzBcTN1qjF/wNW6L@Gb0dahRoFt4aOkPiJemkCkHNBF8MXK9sIxaudw6lGbwUiHQe3wVzy1UY/Grm1p9p3pmR6K3OWFJQXgZUbewEIDpzNvaTCGz304cJiw4negUz1XwwmUxs7wsypsZ3PYE1xGOnPPZhi/CIuQQSq8fDYhISU35XleWviOuS8@2JdL56Ul8g5TwthAhhPPpdRQPgTr1D2JCKTLbVE3sJ9YzvF7fakr@dhx8XzF/@6NgSzG@lUYsLoltd3nEMXE006Q0UWlUOBZHaUewkmzdFmU@vLgEBRr1tWdjaMk@c4Z8G0bq/X9k@qZjB8TvozEfRjTZ18YD8Neh17FJPTEguRUIDJSMBqhy/QmkhNihbJLAPeAgvhruUyYSrg7audgkrvbMSdvqgmyPxZMg0T7WtDoLdjHDRNOuZXZUpjyb5cLaovgJrs0Kk/2DtrKbzBAwaoZq2W1zEoteRuOlOsSP9tHLFxfRuLyMl2hLPbHHXHtxb70A/W1tvSQxRqJ0@hvXLZMWxeJtKQF2i4D5pjD@HvDFotrzJDrKo4K6@MnIfQxGUCNinYExZLGxzTfOURl9xs5idpJ2GlGqfO8tmyUS1ESCFzmojEJ2yMTr75hhT1ksVQEmQFvPbuPrjTVkNU1V62CmSOJsE89m2AONCzehiEvQVoUgJQJbQRaChgNgxAuJyhkcwqC7hHuDuLT90BJn2qqe@jIdpAmlmlXvsdARG/Oao1wslkSGzkvFIgPuuy0O1RSAvSXnfF0eqCsWuQPNoEGrSpGZIL8t8SIUb4Qj8qlYHQ/oREL75fmL5hnAmu1m1@q5eMf2bSgruM9H6fnpQaMQT8ksWGXfda02dqjQXneRoNEmNuCGYpqa8xot8zbaJxgMt09q8GX8uLvPARUYeUGkRsJkWDxwbsabmraW60VAkQvgM4sVgFiK0PDB4T5h/tDWErflwv5nP8Mj7eTY5v18ptG/SERz6TI8tHKO5djHm2eKslnTc@nKg826YYzOZGaksluPLsxep3nYTZ3JMsuwbCq1pedfnw@1/NbLmvp6UpdrhUryvP7snD179sXbxtu4PLmYymcxth1he0fXsgYJiJS2WZHhvfSis6aWXmta6XIU4J6d4VF18racStWidfiT0yu4uKdaVa2q9@tv38Zr25CmyfQsgidAsaMH88Biuh4/sSwrxc6GXrsNt9NjdX6GYYRfiURMYcJCqXE7Nph0yG6ya3a7431jyu2tyBhfByMR9sk3X7x4gYYXdLE3xyI8h878OEoNIxdhelr/s59s3CSvnjV2/uzbg5S5ga8jfH3v5gmaT7TcxxsbHz98mM0mgUrc/Oybz76xu7ubfZTMPavl7meV9MbOn/7Jxoau7@ipjbrnafVo7fz8C1lPZ2X1z34cbTx79nXPw2zBK8M0MOKzALeGOtU5ewPXeYfhn8xv2iGzgeZm5w3TI28iwNaRKf0aEcZLYYW0pPC1wbTq/e3/9oOj15FRpKqnXrjwHkVeR/KFCDeCAb4y/tdFpBrZQW/5m8g0ValUwLj93/49hK9@DeCgy3QHHtWcDys/jVSVCgW5jlTzYNB0HeL9v7/1rbt7fh7U4JKz27p8vw7XFl07Eu5upKRTqQXfWuGedo8xe9QbmQ6@LP6y4cWMsg3t7uNaIpGoqwpcaoMCpTRNP6MumzBzUY9LJLAuM27DQnYzThE24PYiQlwFbEWcxc3CgpiNW7xY9PdiyVV@8Y9zHUuR/MYD81G1CiJQr@pb1QRdG2elEqSk8aCRYtsF2XEeYE9W9EyOslfssSBxVU4XdDmZTD5o4MGgbIKUVCaRGdkYpwyLzNEzwmZfLGwVYX4wNvPzof728frz//3Pf/jnP6DfD@n@T7j9k922OqmtWmwrXr9oVPnFqlW56spXZ/TxgKVLhVIhRa4goOrHTEt/ch3NZaInTJsEl9@zGQmuahUfPhr4VY1wmyo3zeyESzX4IB@zIMv9MSGRfKJGoOoVc2GU2kWdVf0ELbtqDyCbZH27KNerek4/gqzTZMq4IuttesyJ@Cli9@HagB/9NzZQMAQ2@NzAi573udcl10aAzd3XHJ5SpFZL1U2qKQIfDzZKG4VSvqSnGmHrhau8CnTkIixE1G21oOogNt7WNtgx5/Y6S/jXWeLO67mqNoSRDA7eiuJMIlLkH@GqSixyBVf97Vbt7VbDj7omSmpiR6lXEwIjeKmNB/WEcnNTU18mymXx36kGxjJdiTJDI6SkfqMoOy8BWG0ebDTrRPPOA4TOgdNTbbzcAfCJndpOxdmjW6WyotRfVms78yAEcg8eJFDGPgAA1c06iycSm4qyUVuZBgBYjzFoD0AG3uzcVG9qOzc3Ozvw36HnjXiD7c3OrT@9ZtcKPzP3OnLUWS1VPUudCbapw7eaqqKNmjoDQxXe4A@qHymiIJNusa3IkGnbGTAxs6Rt6ZlUbvJxfh90olpdwaZLRalp@Vxd4aLqlcpKCt80Wivk4yrKoobTaeA6L5W9kiKv3n31v@J99u6r38cKH8plUYqktrBdUOTNA3g8sdmTJ0/wfmLb8If7Cb9stEGLJ2hn84fNffh@AmtuQ8WBxEIhLzcS2lRnkR05v41y4RduXdFo9J@80ovbUd50xvVQrzyw/IVl1z/5hVWXFLkuIgVbHuNpkiJU7CEroPhU0XiFj@Zr/D1@g7/XI/ydtvB3/Bp/7PQN/o5H@HvSxN8zD3@nr/G328Tf6QB/D1/j78kIf8@7@JMiFdCyN@@n@@lWWjvXzsFgsbTL0r10T2tjEyBtsvQ0PWXpgaO1wWTCLw0mK91h6S5L22lb08ARDCOWHqGpA68u/DoAxYWflU4j8HSLQSx9AMrPdKD3Ncix@JlUY9FXJmjDqqam1bzVqONm2bVXZ9E67ruoF7OsOTU3zl6xiAfKczmSOjtL8W4ApmfLuJP2zU2j8Wj3dLfRSKHsOXviHM3@R0eD8Ofa/@DIeXLkDBz4Hx0dPTkDdaqaeJBQHsBVqSZ2xOt@pFq@f1ZSsKj6UiGS2rl/Vs0oaM4noKDraJf4wGsGEd7VjTMpykA9uSyT6lO@vChflskQfIKhUQ48CG/cAJZloTKBDYQ7e5EibecSrotLssYHGi/B0TdxQ@rF5Rk2A6B9F/yBHOHPf4C/9f@t/5PnLFarx6GtdXWzE6Mrjr94/Orm6kY8q/FYTHzEduCHFvCNQa5uqmgkT1dgqsXi9fjNDbeDZyy@wwFWMY6dKgWeeYQiHwnipHj5I/YP@8a4xcXOomUWGpg/O5uk0/Fy098WFgeljGsaH42X6ZCPzWZNq//pj2nz3/tx8pTLlsvaFuMfelYvl7P@13ahXC74H5uxWPH2VU3f1/Kg1WSz8Xi5DB/3fbBp@AzAFgCs/5EDqKZntKjwlyNXh0e0LS7IilwkjhtPc@kQS9Pu2XgQQ1QuyffuxcThbfd34/fu6cX09XVgMxyClTZn1Wi0LbfRQPvM9bXckGmgvJiD73Th@hokWDTuuLGneH4HRBRTNPaxXqU4i44LhNgGZ6al9BkWPcMzRiM39sYaJmWcb@rJcdpeP5123LPoT7//7W@fRSsVWZHJNqshAIyF5XZ28tlqNZ8Fc74AlJI3r/hJE91EUYvfbKZkTg0mb0YjwkkrbMe5gIyiO9Rr7H4VCriHF7u6iVC2s2wuHgMRGwft6iaCP26tFYvcnmXzsUKiKH6VjTirQs3Pf9gYzSSyW9tbD@qMfpNlF4rl8pVZ0W4qV2YJe/Vuyi1xMBIu9DLv3csUgaaFdPlM8oV5RZZlrAThgZb7Tx81GhKe2TJ0ozXK8FyxXsP01c@i0VL5ATGHVsixSLQs/ClRqCpYoUhkkKwOruKEtGN1u/p@9nh3b/80qe@A2qIf7O4l9ZPnDyMafuZm3@Scwe/j/d1HR88hwLPH@7sn@58cfr7//BnYe@xydvnyVjxn77BpyfcleyF96b4xTNMwx6bZuByPL1@zLy2rYQEZ@2PLspyuyzyzYZrmELz5VxnuluUZX35puEO62Lsffffdj/67d7/9/Xe//d13v/3Dn371w@/C/btwf5@/v//vijl8/vSr//l33v3Wb4Plf4L7j@D@yU@/@rVv8Zu@/xju/xKy@2Nxh/zxWwJYv/TTr37w459@9cu/Dve/Evev375/5SfL7x9@Z/WN4X7wO@v9fP/fw/17HJbv9/u/xe3wfcv/b3F/v/zr7371P/D/n4ofGn/73a/@MT7Exz//9T/9L@@@/R91vfCn//bdd7//7js/ePedb7/7zvfefeef6u9@7d9q6fDjd9798A/@6g9/76/@8H@i/@/S8/fe5//u1//5X/xvf/F//MUfivsncP8HMP3kL/4j8Ozf/sGP8P@DP/jbP/oR/v@Xf/23f/Av//aX/g0ZfoMb/p9/9e/4869/5T//zW9@769@8q2/@Zc/@Zvf@IO/@j9/@f/6tf/81//97//1//httPyNn/zVH/3SX377u3/5nX/xl9/@asXzu2ufX72H/Vf/CDbvj@f7wHmfdH2ozVc/Fz5/H2rMYgE@AQb/Z@9@7ReBx3@Vf/0P8AX/wOl7wcecC//43uwDIPzmQqCIWZqvGAp6IbEF@vNWsSgqh8B5h0L@9Kt/8eMgil@chzrnBjF@D8vlnNv3sES/@9G33v34n7770W@8@9EvoexWssXkblLR1neiQiNLyb2HP/SYfx9/6BGi/@ILeEwS1AOoJPCLfSE8fPHFF9LkOgVNn/SDa7D9gqz4xbgTuDHh5LsJe5x4GfbDjWnfuInW1@GowayJ7uwNSac3PiQtge/EBpgA3y0pl4EvQh1dtvzUJKSc5jtEBCzuOKFhiwn8pWyRRSDQZJKYQKsIDIkJS4DTwwSrVCoUuDIhr/CJYSasWmDYbQitmwpCh0A8TLJRQBCThwQFQlYSx6yxVZnwgAmEVyUIhBxaHcuaLicKlUcQYWXyiCEsBE5gX72qVAuVSRXBvSUUIKLEQ8IJgVUSk@pb@K4QTAgnRR69BVQKlUSiWsAIMZGcVskGxanlKHGU9gSjdKM9o/mk9x8w9rGsFWTegb6BBOO@8ZmY@b5Pgzr3wf0ssSWSQ3/fSPcWEXyDohKx8GzByDZ4eOEB4CqKqqoMbkVBbB6A84SDSlC08EokRLYCPN5xG1hABmNeJCh/E/QB8UcqWx98JaoST83m5qYUqcoZ@YgGFBLQbnTPS/y8gmuunJeYnC/KaG3SVGOeOnPzGTV9tx5twVOD//4GzQBOsDKhtRnFTqUo4/GxjxP8fvBgi30Mqaf3zE5iSiLjZLFXFxO6k0jIOsRadRLSS5BBErAvAbqW1EmFhjESUjLJmFqJoBs7OjoSqJHFy4qUAO7XMxp@Yw/0eDyOQAhVTarJpHir9CYLVRhUchVvdRNpTp1gTNezZdCwywytWFgh1qDlhJZv376FzKJZAKVDaNMwMSFAzxbIESz4wrV@f@pPP9ezRYk36JiW56eFxujAsTiLSyzGtuISny/KkQjGF6N6oRBFUxzyRI1t@fND8prk901R11To2GtsZRRycd9x74jtHT15sv/0dFivM0kc0d4QZz@vE58xDLf79BGfTq4X84hGpFbDmE9LOkojab@URjwSh4@OD09KjNNE5FAsgBQvU7@jIEVRkyLD4YudiBhDl/FoAkc@wWdplv6YXsxghNWyFGmZqCoDw@GflaUnXvehM4HWZFKWk1oex4fj1HPHpG84pVLlrZbdluBN32OGW@XwdXVQOnHSsbqzQ0STqlcKdbaiETI4L1WrYjIK06Tqyf4pBDg9YpqeVhm0Na@y23o2l83pmXw@t61r2Xwxm88VMlAb5NM5XdeK2WyxUNy@kapfsImKuCpg7lf6pt0d9TZxCoh8lpZD9NispZP40zMZeALEpJbbrm9s9K8URPCM2OIK5/LcwOeVghT4CC4mfSSxj8AKLogDJ@gwMTvq8KgspqjgCvYYn6ciazko3HHpDBiJg5OG4as89zWEsgRtz9AtRTa@@c0Rq1ahzaccHkgREFk95s/ZUKy22lOJqdpj1yTXLmNt63MLT69Q25Y37BtTKKhpVYrc3Nx0ANLhAQ7s0ScP0cbnTYtsmmC@mRjS/3/9A147fIeXKk7Cd4x2BVcL0b4SUNziV@1K22nRiTblTqVWpwOKym216bSnqjeaghgU2ViJNvtO6zzqO1p4ZCAugKukjJTaQOEychqNSiWaSkXv69u50kbKTam0oRWLdaCw3tfz22B5ZnPbWAdscmjzct6qWGqrPlJPgGkhnF7S87mbHbHNWxXShKhVEZErgV/JdmzzBqfPl4wOSOKrFp8jVZL1XEEu18qz7@28XK7fPBiYbctgZ2mcMn21NGA@L9/4/iBqE4obrciJDfBYFVx4UUqfpeMrAqchMKBMmEo7YmeZKs35qYHQqOPJ0rX6jr/nDNTakq4rekbJaIqWwf8dBh3/7@9fh7@OTwiV0aVTXHf1FLIbhKPNHuPmtyOHnToOnXP00Gyt8LHXM2hy057reN7fw89Dwz7nTo8svtlJ4PSpgRucewNr1Fvh4/lwgOvBTPcfDcL@oAkIIg9yDw/h4fYdZ5mHbfb82YpUPgm2FwNi8P3FwPvx4Sefnobep/u7e59Kefbw6OmjhVdOeMqxx/sHp8HnNnf1g@YCEN/Yf/x48VO8IliNYofcBstt@wZNwtmR96ARcU8Yc/mZMY3GF3zhjuUFs/X4Cq2SdOqv5qHyYTVN1uJL9CbShK9wF8qNtl2UpCGznUu2nWZtp9838Iy3zgZY9gxcpWBidd2nowgx6kvH7behiJkb0hNcEFHU8CArREL6FIAMxi1aTmqNJNwvpY2nr2EHcBMPkB7jCYcrLOGFVmh0rW5vxEaXju9BahoGg/tDLwhvhq/ReosRj4Psbrn0b3uXIpIxMiKFMjBsuW2P793TnrnA3NVCulQ6S98Ad1UemuXmeWloTkaeOfT2J8BsbMyeA/sbLkrJ3mYKm6RsMyfnW7Je0rYOWDbJGmojYmwh7btWpcZOQFWpD49ZYUx9mS0jk90C3RVrfNDXaDcd6a9/83eRh7dSIK4imizjPM0NTVJJzdOLhVyhmNELyUKxkM1p@VwuqelJ0KK3i6DopLWCli/kilqykC1msqA3gWuuuC1F@GSY1BaBhHcJwNotPHtphzRFtVeVInxEgL2JGXEWMYLvMZNNCCPjabtQ2eBCsC2rIutZBu11aCQARIO1WOTgYC99cCDLD/EDRz/30rLcxo9cIZ3efijLJrnsgW6ny7LDwxRwobo84h/p9MM9WR5zALjHmyz38GM/j70Asmzhx97uwQHG08EPHcODt3Puwj/6/sc2eLPxI5OhbgRZfh2AA3@7PKIsYbqPHxgnuhxwlz1wk@VPfHzSaYBwzP1xCJ/6ad3dleVD/rG7iy57lPAcR/Uz/NilS5Yh47F8yHIXDF2s9WS5CUYsJbLcAlNraoAdnnSFG4HZI0OWp5xASCJZnpBvo3UuQ0Nc2GM0n376qdEbtc0uv6Yuf7cANXCxJuP9g@YnnzS73aY73d3/5Bhd9vY@NTrTsdvsNkWwZgMuB8KAy/lgungBjoeNhtFf6vIZuNgLLo1pw0TcGsZrwElcXYxk0NgDlz1wWTaYwqHBNQCvTbweDuD90GiSi3@RC70nzaZcRkbFtfx0XCWUGTo5MjkwWq5Txu9JZYOxaCyanNby6XqZHNgANLV0@YbOqYzR8eDYqAWd6mpam1TS9cqksq3zwfhOTD6b6DlLTm4M7mtFUMOM@5qeTUxKuCDU6URZVNHux7R7W29iT0HdymRL8tn9@4pc0@r3da1Qym@/3BrLcryEz/uZ7dIbaHNFocmHj3htu34fdLtZkO3thJHSS9vb8fINkGMEtWgTG5uNWOzSNM7jcUQXmyaQBH5K5pTSaZU7sUlyUuFYsWm8PKloZb5HDUvfgtXGDdHGrZHjcohdADe5ny7ROZyyVizIEH8qFYvHQTKREIH3bGLNi6@fnp@efgEyCxp9osn0jB/uVhafn3y6p0IrSnzhRmbqAarKjqvuoWCZc@H7bPlWpyB31U@hKgS11bfDKfqu01f3J9CQRX3bd/C3p1HFpiLq6adzcFAI85hxhWOZlr3bLZPhPm9WmxmVKpiMNjTVSdwZ8UuqhBvVaqVRGfCjNKtBqM/4WeQzMIcexz1Yd0nBr3DaunBoVNI3M/9PxwP2kHuio4H9YI3KQ6jV02Ub9zc18XOTTSITqdrGLeAeVh5ejUvYVXJTNismHjkqR3BV9H27MrY9o2M@M11cZnx4tAn1DE52hzaCyeKb7IwOKN1DpfxGqbrMnsMlZijVJvYuzFmGPpF8oKF/3SfMFS3BwEHMG2jhxF7Gy6/hy91ksbb6EBol2XI79pA14mCVftV51WE6y2fLdG5TjGAZSaIgHf4Zr1Q/A12HAz4vlQAZwQnnABRjArhWmxyM@NC6KXcrNfR8jY8dRZbrilK7rktVRXkhVaHolqcRo@KNm7RRKEs3NT2dL0/ATtvOlnusWWm@nJTdyhAa2Kzch9wXvQp8ZYlRBhoCpQDOm2sWe/eL34rvKLkKtywTsOs@6BNQz1cms6zKVGp6Np/U81nshMhn4NaSekbHCeJJPV1M6hrU1lCLQ3i4t@E7Czf4gcpc17CrItaPyYzJyfQkrWpJzdSSQPT0K6v9Kp48j4FiQkSLJ0fOPh56ChbISMC89AlvI57Qt/qxtsOMHYVYGaRJmdJpJHtsaMED4RybRp/7jysssxXrb8bQ0@bpeLhfq5dK@5Ph18Eppry@n09spxNv4vFyDERovOKZr6VqWaqi8CEqDDeAtUUPDPPGg1p6A9J9pTSUG8ju0aa2rZdq482aokEC09fdHbkq1xnk2A0Tyg4KFa7vzDSWmV0DtWs8PphpRb0sqTTWTdFpMb24aoFCXMLZawKgNBQCEanLYmeyv9IqFo1u69FoPFrGjtoNWfSvgRTkJxGDOI7e0@7LoGPJJbmoo4eZMKXFNOmwmnUjYbuZZYtS5Eq6ubrZgeZniqY9gUrINsikqNUHUqTEGOh6Z2K7htQGYx86myqxU33J32c4xRLgSrSTUI3VaYaDaWGbiX2OCwfvsyggZriDmq5n6jV9G@pAkKu@V13XytgNHcE5nGoVKO9dAX47iSrOuP@MTadGQvEpe4@xbmJTokRHFsm@W9ntHu@W/a897Pw6k2RZLkflyFU0Er2Bn@RPBWyZQIa3ERILbO/K70Mp4Yb2MaPEhUCtHn/71OpfFTIKb@aDXLq5iWym@FoBna8VYJHQagHAzZ82/dkrPQdZZDu@BTSDRlAhQO2Wy2EvXiT1auh9Uy9knhwe2Y/cA9OfL5ltyNUIS2sKzkkul4Rtjs@ilIsFXdbPkxH2IFKOsHMlqpVoqjUbnhRfbr8svHzy/Oj50YEUOdu43nCwh5f5VGFv7a99HTxGM9koY2eVyKSSLYs5LdWqou3o7D5UAgxPk@5oeSV9XeXcWyWHvA4u737x17OTnQJ866DgliAHcwm9WtW2dBaPDN999fu4AP5q//PdxyzqGVP2d3/yY3377/7kX9NMkehN2aMexO0I@ESjlt@OXF0Nr65u4OJuuUg9wpHKbsfBzLuutchsLncpZRhb24ms/sAup4RfbVuLRzwlIjrot3MR71o46ekCOPk96GQl5zELIvvHVk7XHuxgdmrB0g82G041vSJwS@HJq2vG4KNVbXe7lk6mVIqV3ips562yw95iD/RbZYO9qlRxyFLDBSN@N@tWtVpFKCxaTaS2okzPgVvtplxPMOqmhTbhS3PL3jqbZ@izDVYs2mBveluij/9sy4PG3ZZNP3PL8@DT/zK3vvSYjKMQqVS7TTuD7JgsV4X830oBOmfxd7/4a7qe/7s/@ZXrxnXjC6gaisViXtMjP9N@9jPwsGatst8yox5pXFSMhqBFx1acfKq2oDGJx@F2GPfvt@@wRcdAa7C6NjTb8Uu6QFWIsqbBN8Bpx8jbFi5lTJJiTdtTxMuSFCigpDi73VaSYLAt3Hsayqx0JX2ETlCzsgpIS@mjGSiGp9b3@06r4fXH7pBmSMconFZPsnsQBGL4CHcM2hCHy5PIVUBKpbZuB@Uoe0Q1UorYwPQ83H8IKhHpIwjyGNieDrRiQwNXC6NPywYZr6IXwpMc2jWIuw5x93mABtnGKPXcQ5Jx7HggG5Rr6SNQDIgKFigMzNoBD2UQLB8BASANMQHYqrMdlomzKyuRKM82N7rBeaf8THmxfFDCYAitjStj/cBl9AdWoNTjmRXIFyKHQTsLWfpAOAw@KlmBZgEGpy/UuGgp8XuDAli0bUeMksbu3ZthValY7TijFCH8c2uInVOUD/ZyXAGY36D6uF2Sk8xOJDCzP5pnO6B4gtAFrlP4flHlUFAm4@eNJMH/vZkWOXIhq8ihjAkQ@cVLRQtIBoGR7DwPW2ynwjR9O84C5FuAe4uQok2Nglbi2eRjVf/Cd7wBDH8W8fd9lfAU@VCHn@DbxaWqDKrDMW66iRuWcGEglpjyLUlQih2O/NBBKEiK1SffHcuFNgyNivr7G8UyWhyDzfaDIjxoJqmeZTilMxfHF4VC3wzeBu7kI@LZoF76lgMZ6g0dm7b@oW0KcLYscATIKLGDCkd7bF/iJs0ibyhwGCOPdk9BzkeMaSsjOveKwuIwY9OFhq5PmyQzuyprDdpML7IYMRrt9GIH4OIUiBBumrjplus0@@YAUDoxTYa733ilVKoLStG4SdvdPLGAr3oHFlQltpcSR4ylLq1zK3WKm0wqTgc0aLF4OIJ6FBY/PqIptpbpO84561vnJu/Hjc0tvfaYnk@CzpoEys5uIGwJu4z1TJKlwTnJfcG9Da9tbiwkQ2E3YtP47XdG24g1MEevqU6yXDw@7MKwQ/Sl61oSrWBv6vmbN9AWBPCtBiLXFMu2K1FcMRrsRyCJbSgqtAOCin35wxi0OP3tG9AIqrh5AT4UTcI6BoRmy18IjaUYUvsRVQBU9qBk4U5OI7eEy/cBE7cda0HREwLeZh@zjC7RsS20t4bYBwNgYNZX5qGDGwTFdHijNmSMytfegFyB0jlogxsuGxXsh@F97kYz7bI1Y2@2IcBhpUNxVRgvFv5HLvSBpQP5mZK@AY55wHAJJhsxOQFgE3Jc5qCD8IvBObdLJEtK7DakJEMIgtQAhVQF/3xBFtpNWQKHh4bH9/MTez5dXl6qtPnY2LVU08Mdhj08NDE17FqgEzupkTkYirNcLDzdS8CdmRS@sTgepXl/QodYFu9N@VuSOl5FzD@IRTteFCvHC9xAtzugTUtwtxCPGOrAos23WzExZYLzn15PXvn8V0L@UwrRGwTCGIKZJKfJVhKAJZut82Tnsl0WDhdUIAE45KLpW@J@f67/MfB8kzXsBD6cEc1N97@b/fOW03dQJ5F57@osap5C3@fU/xTfQ2sCgWzzku26rjGNkXscfSMDx6ak9rApVPvkAkaoZtgV333OmtSm9bngkyA4VGrBcLKLO5JIV@uB8q0I0X3C3SfgPuHuk1mkfrS1SZ2rZGh1g8lBrseNrHyfCGbq@7nh2/bNXAgyKNZM4yDQ53TO7gbuVoVC@/TmX5CPFZ8xgCeGQHAzlqq9PKud1W3PvNyqJ1JdYHaZCAE5DqBrdaLpZTswI/X7F/2h481Z2bh/GdRKAm@0avUEN3BewTQGGUSMwell4ZZT3YHKu4G4QiASDBBQDwNHVA12RzErXg42tCRHYJyaPKMxR6wmkKmT9iWchB2oS5z0nLBhQPUQILQPkgRoggvzSw7fT96XDi9cPFDX96vQFtgD3PokWo8CJReKCpc1ZcqkEFaK4qMJZEd1tbKYFN8dsqK24BRK5o3I/zD6Gx@MfgfKxXLsiWF5hVGWwkUFJ2SBCiGKC1GVVSuhfAUMUltG33Sh5trn@qmorSGarZTfzODxYBK8Szw@LxbK/Fac5w@tFpJtuRSwwrRSgSROK7xY8nLhk5QTPAjmiWBTnxFEeC5AAEZ6aTBTBJuEg00qFS442GRFsMsQkhNCcsKDcN@TFUjWRTBoPQXnrmL21EE7xelfMsDTeDUKatBQZniGHg5Zf4nbMuFApohzJnOICwQPoYqNfNaqL429FkI6JLQWACAj3gLQ5kfTlKRFgacpwVcgozgpfRnFvwQbcFkBDEYiuMy3LowFTEZtYFD45QTVA1B25URNkjWceka/NL/lpG/p39pty/S8T23eMp1c@P2jWNaRsqECGtI@tHQWBTK2ZJ6L04bndI4InuLWc0Cra146LLZE2Qb7lH9QcarZd5qpgYHTRPDAiuD44rjffsAREfZg6IyMkZPNlnijySK2WxY/bzNYXduBpkl4y1LQ9dqO6dnREWRqy@nalmcm8cBkrrKbNGmB73sshfVkYXQ8SRJ9k7wZi6A5X6Gq22jgEVqNRswz@514KZg5ip8qsmc0KmH7F0yh8CCeBNCjYczBo@BH8bth4u66Itip1TqPHQ2FYxQi2WUgw1qg/4NrDzQY5jmzliPt84mqdHMUow2we87A6YLWN/ZUCUMvgD@cwUaEjOGQcEkyA5u0pdAWy1RKYq2kERdBP/vgoOwzPWbEg/D6PIA5YiSZu0hjpKy7JLrGyuh4MD@@kw/H9ySM78l6fKkVvogzb5pXuOOHRZ2JzSCAxxkambvRwKSD3GrfQmcOlcAa9Soe4L1RbNM0rDZiugted4V3tQP8kQy@PPgKEP98Ff3XZ6AffP99s8/AcwVPpiBvBjg7MEb7nnv@2GYMvB/G41JkSXQBaz96z7jAL54KcYAqBKixJLhs3KIQCuYQmt1esHG2D/gOnsfZVLf4nqZYVbjjEpzciyQ711dn0aNG2@wbU7MdEz6TIbh@io@hwUby6v0SjoKOhJ7D23oxqLvigStU40h07qm0gmWM5EU8vpqtuBcr4B7qKScMD1fTD91viWbs4qvw3mpoB0SjuF2WfWFh9@dwOpzyXXD7tFW3L0d5/cNzEtdE300QoIPYCyQ5iza@Tnwex4IkvUeNEPhV55OMm1T6EHH/x9t5@GEkujulkLmhQBU/l6X5Hd2X57i1LsdDXOHzJB83ej@WvIvp3pvnQqzGgc1E2N6HVSG3IOOEjFYrFobIbdbmmGPfkgloR/109opapbFEoAYhSdKNLGpuk34Rl7BlfAhv7HD6HN4IsGuOGpyh/LRhn5Y4R4KRy8AYhrQWYQNKOkAJUZGTXKAR8iX5ZvB@dRPE2VoZZ@tWnK25OIMSMB9lyJPUmotS5AJmz7os6Jud0QrpjE7YdobXOrENl@0YLvZWXEWtaMlKsuhFtAQCOWpGS/sxEMrRdrT0iAxetHRChvNo6TMwzMpW9Dpa8osFenDhkwwP0F6IcPxuRUt7sfiNNDLOTc@PV42WgjwFP/f5J1EESIHpBq0Rh9hsRyRz5JpQsZFSmWTIMV4Sm0/UD5OkOw1/fkYD7fWOjtjHuUWeWYJpc5VGqMbg8UC14e8lvKQkl0Rtvn90QBOaAi8YTQLaeOEwBB7U8Eh0XhhxxNCVRjTgDQii3Cwtx4iFarL3REfEDhxKmTwfP1FPJX2gHSP3GniuzyKhgzlEeD@/5kHwDHw/PDHwKjxvoeNHRxjhmGx8CVpI1FfRNYnCvJ7HReR@OIeor3veEx7M6XvhuURgQzIddDganMPIhs5wnknIFSfIW@Ew1CnHCyVy70IwkgqiZK5wJmuRMhQM4cIfX5ecUDhEbU4EoWMtXeelLKgXSBaj00zWhTRVXvgAhZDMgRJuts7p0JNHwkj@uLhJUl2xqhryw/IoSXLNi0kIrOLmLmNjxGMPGq/7uOXLhzVf/ZAT7GuJIYBQyCAWLl@dD9DfHa6/@wq1T4SFCJYp1sur0tvq9dpadgHz/iza2xmIjkn2KL5UOQpimJEcWgchzXwdr91S8XHKB1fyeaQB9AVt3ydb0Ca4g26LbQsOC7UE92Le8lwHy3N9NaFuayT9C9VXWlSMScDhCQ8wnSVtPa484cuyGF2of9vof3AGu/MZHM48hEcJcBdIzku5O7ZplsusbIPY5jYoUrUS44KchkuDbJ5Zgrinodtg2BYsjhrHj46ePv4GVLrb29txUUdPZ/hhqcW@1qAe55Bp/nRQHyxptuhJPMcAB7uxO54Owd04s@VbsoQLa1AGDIjFZz9RxuNCloXk@ULZhXDcb4iiAtb5rBgYc1IJVR0Dq2xL0HUEBDFHsS1DAPHVW6B3klprcdqxv9HAg08bDaq@Gg2cvNRoiFoMs8YfEY//LLKRGnsuHbzGj5u4lCRaE88eHbEXn@6estNP99nB873P2DeOnrMXu09PcW3zs@cPHx/uMbj3n57sM2ludiQezYMNSqDrI7Nl4rlouDNWlhHkPWc45XInthfn9ifGgH3qtEwcptrxjMGDHv9QbXNU5aH2oTk6xT5Mi45fGlgjnG9BZwdBMxaVmzYtwMPp/gz8NqFNO8A278BpWx0L/ErY9h1apuevA2N9C3IQ5K2/VjTJlSQ8JoimDtGBXjgD6xKCG@Afx24AjMHnX9HZspbHA5htlQnCBdcHU/B0//jJCcPV83tHTx8dnh4ePT1hB0fH8PnsG4dPPwF6Hp6cHh8@fI5O5PHJ0aPDg8O9XbLgCKRVhuvXvxx7o7UoqOidqNI6x5FvOkI4@Jrv9UYNnl0atBTRY9GxjdLHMvrWG7MdLUtjD9UXXP5IQwUstrl7/MnnUOcz8zWOcPpDwTT/QH7u0XFVm2m2Q7FBYalCeSuL4grVnqLFaTxiMGW4e71ZpqXqMTInmQ@cJvG0LZPJezhHBfu@@Yp2Kss@aIhoA2AjKH/CSoXRqRPRaHKHQFYhtlbfwV3xeGx8EqH4wKAP/KkmZYkoJubKIFBcrnBoY3@QVg4sgO/BQhfRjlzugWUCC@6BZbkFqqKHOHeE5YSP8ehojOKZ5bnFl4PhAQ0Ls@3A4qFBrdiCwInnG2WpwYJTe3B9f5/OFuG9PHTmmeG1LIuCeOQfz93o93nBMPmJTyAT@VAizW0DnzIImw4ONYhpb/zAQ3QFbsB5QkZn5LFYJa6yU5wcZNoWP9Wl2zdsPgVqNnWHeI8VcAeXiphmawWnodACkKFDDIgnMc3jEYR7JLRC833DQciHt2I0xBxJOpHMn4J2FwIPbyHw84ABQMpcS6dFNRWtOEUwTkewcsxzgCOx3/Zt2D@wc3vcMucCiFlbsS@tN2/igsjJuXaSP0@RsIMsemO6oFbSUGbHcaGMk1il8yNQCrZ6znBk8TyMzaeARpyomgPfWLFBbK8q1bnYkA6LMdqOHYq0CVy8ItYmMOX7xEocz8fOA/E1O0wQOB8qYT7vDtExmniE7mzsLImDSJcmdr@AIkxj5dj5OR0RJlz/lGay4y3D88gKleqjh2fK21dJPJSMiwV@DqA/6RBvYEyMC4oHjfPRhEUX9S5R0vzDZLxxE0OLOXhCWmIp94FBO7BnQbvuQaMcuPHpxrftcX3Moj1ZXl9XeCgFJZM4GtLrxWbSLclqfpRJClNnYgpISHYCsiDrY75NkmAG8voBroTBXCgDRWyUI9huXziqRYgQP3XNcQckizgxT2R3AD/OqjSjYnaAKC5sCedH6mXsYSVRjadmE0pYiJwxX0QnfchaPB6alkL11S1wj9aDA/n9/uAKa7Hj1cMHQXu0FtoH4aYkVsPi1VII1vuDfbsGLK/cfi6wkPbkasC8krwNLeD0gDmTm5FgNu36GF/dyjsqewAG617sQQmAhmIb2zRE7e9BG@MB4mEwM4Xo5PTR/vExk3n7BMKC3MMmQ1uIQYS9wZ7NZttaNgk7NVCagsZyoDz5NnMz2vxrXWFeSrwVokLoIElBj0BYzI7K7VgTLvVEzUIqBM2@J4HoU24euytfBnk1AfgG2oCA7CzTQgmUliYzwisfywtPAhd0S3LdODyHn2ZY87obz6Fzp2FA4TlBRhdXlizPvxdcPy758XAFy3w9pgS3QZOG@gbaCScQ8RA8qup8Dq7JFj9LcZI9V7AjPu1w4ld6XsP@@zMUMRJXwrkuHBLrQjkWqHH9eNNXc2hCIlYDBs70FI58RjM4@CKebHbCGRqfVXqx@SoIlEw8mexBmCsgeP2mHByVHZvVk5VAIQ@XtU3CpuZjWcfeWQG7vNrTxzgXOr8oHhajAmm7NirlHyYqXkvMxeTTfGlifEeAnM/lMnfBXkyFH1z5@8Lmdcii/BwNhtC@n4H0ph517wPnHj5N@u4zBlhDOj613i8wCwFB1VlSp8ylnSqjMH6AC@8XAmRwN2g87G0x1jibLOC2HDqvkcLQycutNISKcJBQXmpuUf9mfXQokO@Mb@PD4@OFDT3h1MEbnJX/xHE9c7YqL7TRSsgK17XO25mua5M3vp5pgFBitIxp7WI7Wm3HJ7zyVKEjjbeFU9IRq5P4tNuk39dAkVD3oornO2LvXnmxe0/RyuGkHhw@3mdbtCNeZ64vUnbleEj2bFj2OgRIBlO/BFYftIbvY68EN@CQ9EECmWg1X4xoE78TN6IIaM01OoVDTAsVslVbzP2O1zJs3PUjKX/sMTl5DwJSL@z@0UF8Wc96ujwXHpDzhnYMQiVlRZUpKNhhhy5CmgfBcxPtQxUWrtTwZ0quOZXbSGmFdL4oUers5Cg5qBXrya1WRWZQ@Rr2wBu7l@3zrtO76LA@G37ZnLSmb14zlsuyDMSl3@O7oWr5Soq2ktyGZ4EV08S5AsH7tLPrmcyYSifG4MAym7XDyxssTgZqNJdwhcQCl7Ktgc@FuMRuVBnU8vWKXUmXBzW7XsZFfqNEZZTQEjG0uAe1KMgYPjJfG9WxTg33upr2BcMDIulAL7E0hNHSELB5YriW83j36SdzvXGoAGAXmJjrTR3q/GzHj3A2G649UW3zMia6yZIMOVZCBUn6iFYFabiknfqTsTumbQFmkCtJ0Ga9CT2ncemjtDoejhxyEREpyFrs2rqWPvKXMaWpRwG81Ky6j84OwZn5ieHAELed8lnUisbVNQ3XTsZDIGoYksShfCbLuKYQERVruWp1yVNNo9VDJPAw02sKxnZ26GhTYDVPpV48nMphuLRgIl1HIw6AwGtIow0YBWnuHi37kCD5@K2hgdtQH9WI1snQBHmJNEV0wenf7IrWN1H4HSAAJ/xHXOdSRRen0LxAkeRrB6lzAbclm2/44zADLqvkmfIRJhZh8/gqM@A0U5xohNEKMoH9R5dITk4ruEQKFI2@biUj8B/n3okkNE4tvjykJWUpOVXx1Z8Fi4WCKX4w33OIFB/dSQ3s6YLm0ZP/t7in3Upj2fJ3@ikqYCKt0A0mGiNCgogJZ4zmCsbjUsNpocGeg8ChUeEkzrozP@YFZv7PI8yr3He4v@Yp7uyPqurqBhPPylr3@EO6u6p27dq1d33tj/JBrGai6vf7gDTT4klEDnwk/15Z/6quPzzDOi808pyem0vPxdIdTmekolwOTPBRpi0zUyr9Jcp3L1JRtuxcXSVBixcHerrtwJIkylv8Vt7QmQxbQZS5rLuSuVInbMcSckbK5wW9zylPY2U0g@v0M06X/L0me15jGcv7Nl4//lqyg3wynpW2JgkudQZB/w1PWjoF2SwF1BSCi2N/E9uxUEofTDmcwAoOz/lJbMulCMpqQY04JDOp8vbblCMXGW8ySTTYi3FOsBbIiEElqnOVCDclh0Woh5KfGiAIJjKaUJJbVoVnsvDMAIu5nqpq2QtyTsChaUkRL6Ff5Ff8p4Q9jpzKl16c@IQxn3Lj2bs5TiAadJ@mFpMpPpqguwh/lI36xiwS1T1LQlw8SBwYp8C6Tp99sLt4DP5UjxPmQKFGijm66xRJ6ShDQbHvQ12IiffWP9wV650Ha@xR35@KCm4zPPLCsmIO7hh@NsTAThSKJrwZjfqodaQF3x25UMtAIWvrqG6JIBozu2PV0bKH82fxSTqkQyFHHCLkOzQQiRLCmx7e5I6KHQznBEMrnrgEE8eqDGZ8oAEy82KN3cx9cROy1hR2@z0TCe45lh6kdDjy2r5jwRothNWPxU3tsnzL83T0G8EAYzClbVnWX26C9q/Vd6jPfVXIvygYJLuV6uC88@Jl5GAFRFIJa3lYxq4XXlqWoRtus244hwCzYh8n@k/Am/6tPxj4VgVmDMoYwqI19Me3fsexrCNfK4ERLrIyaibRD3t4M27z4Q4sujxgRvQSDrOsDgMOw1@cn1ld3CZdWdZCpVWkbYauvg06SEDlcdIdonaYFBYYJoDpgYWu/QkQZcUWcZRI9yxxobXLNR5EATUwzomhm9BkGAwnQRt6hk6yrD6AYjVIVNmgk8AE6mv3PXQOdhYhgO4xEQUUAkqV9C0cLKk0/0M4CNkwpWP3VM@4MPoNSVZA3P1xAKNvRGDqFSpm4A4d3Hxfb4jG4V7zpHJUE/D88ejwU323tit2TknHjYpyim8r3h/uw@iitemsNT@ED6lKA0qmKMGqHJyK2s8fj2qNhjg8EvUPH/frAA3AH1UOmvVaIyvqB9X9413SvgMEcXDYFPv1D/UmZGseZqlWVcyKyonDPfGhdlR9D6@Vnfp@vXlKNe7VmwdYGWr1K@Jj5ahZrx7vV47Ex@Ojj4eNmsCGWbv1RnW/Uv9Q23WgfqhT1D7VDpqi8b6yv59o6OHJQe1IkJGA0cqdGmBZ2YEtLNZE7dytH9WqTWxQ9FQF4gGC@1nR@Fir1vGh9nMNmlM5Os1KoI3aX44hEySK3cqHyjtonJX5DlWgX6rHRzWMf4SUaBzvNJr15nGzJt4dHu4SrRu1o0/1aq1RFNb@YYMIdtyoZQXeGUZVAwygFqTD885xo050qx80Yc44/oj2DjZ08gkQBrCsQNFdIjCaQWBrgUiHR6cIFelAHZAVJ@9r8P0IaUrUqiAV0KKi2jSzQYVAxKbZTHFQe7dff1c7qNYw@RDBnNQbNRs6rN7ADHU0yDgF1oFKj6nV2E@AFz8Cs1qKc7PUnaK@Jyq7n@qIucwNHNCoS24hslXfS5o7GDDXOEQJhnhm4F2bByvd@U@3PsafnD@RWXxGoyMmVQ93azAjy2BVqSjhGGadzUQoJTMNZhqdCK@xkDUd//Km1woG3SH6mOpifPBxHfayePWJjTdAnFvfuGFCnq9QgXS61fpUacFGt9Fq2dnHlIyh8b0S8hj8W7ls2UYMjY87bzz42dpium/HCFV@LhWdZKiHCgjMydR/zqZv3rVvC9ft@LIYOu8jYHV0FLLa5ApVKTA0krMjXlMRVUknE/QeSHagghkF3mm38JwULSMp0zCEf4Ov0QtPDsYHGJ35uMt1cRNLaAS/@6oaroRCItA/GZEg6FKVTuj7v/YyebM63PM7veGwk7FtVYbyTmAf2MvY3yl@6fcSxXPJ8oQsqZ1lNP1Q7btpCaP1z5JkQvaLM6aWZfBfa0I/tsKGYz7gqSlVRYfV8tAy85yLo0VSVsjQFuheQZ2Ma74PlZ/rJ7iby6@9LCa@v9ffWbbQXhDj1MKEd0blLujn/QVnAAGjWBxAkkBGyHBdo4yyN9GZ7yDjFWai6wZorr7yaV4HksBC9sbrm3XibDwOpib2MA6/O6p82Dne24OhE7F9ubn@aqNo6bBbP2f59xTroUCvFHVsBPM4rNMoyZCSKix8SFKMcNsR@xMDuy5mxFjrqtPoI8Z50HYbcUsmHMiwuSHe2TJAE72Uj3RICQrA8dRS/LpQMiUDZGJNtbE1196UlvgerJWIB6QxS39GvTbFfwhbi78Scd0gyUCSxSi8LnAu7C5o3EvtKVNR2txQ4B7M4qQUH3MYN00DOuoi@1n0rqU3ydtGL4ZsyojySt1OJQGJp0kshLKrGLBkf6Q4I/IAmKKHwZefJb/B46kMcEfh7rxwUpk0gIx7uiSeU0eH0bLRZxLyRbkEXfT8ua5pW@Apvy2RItmTx8k6MIghDYTKBRoVlkQCcFHHEUlWSRawb5dt8YU5FYN3IJyi5Fj5Dpy7qDkSSlHFD5HvKiqFYFg6yAlT7U7XYakspzqOhSJnjEw/RA@C/yfSZAH8bdhxAvSIWkYQwEdRkqAyrWD7SkQJ7pSiwdBuRNQ0P51GYO7NjrnSDZPamyn71wAJZO/M1IdTCnvYzSwgADI5HmyY8qtN0q482Dq9TdmyOOpJBu3rUUbIuUJNFXNwcxsXWVp2ZZVuBV9sYfNZk1HhPhQVb3njdklSD1umxFZePAtTDM5W8T/cFToA0QJPXHrFVqtJzspLKVPjgAy1ZEw4HR0xCZal9w9q7VaEESIzNvZLzZciFIAuIz7z7aRLQIaCzXPjERdpJhZNioKHEcFxm4yTjwxZd0mGmH0f4Tzr0GEI3hMyucMJos/QKVRfBE1knpGhCFYSWR1GcQZxuLUdIC1Nq3caezqZRA7V2B8POFa9z6daKofDAT4khqa7vCM@eDNAuf@4ZjOLuSuNYRZtF7EyPpaQ5fFOlPZwOIalo4ftBhyzwcx2xIk8dPAH4c1Yxi@E@SwYyxMJteiHanDZxLt3mmY4hDuhFgYT9FboOMQf1KRrHy1EOTzJNLchMsC8ikfL6tAxmK4WRGY7StkGmlBYUiLittgQX79yLiaoDBnqEwWDUG8uyGaT6kG9gxa/u@H4V5z7cQk06PgdHZnUAElngdxJ9QHFeGxPuOmjYUgnGtAVeAKiKVHggzRtqApz9CvJTtKuKRVFx8TYpdSSP16PZlJlLQUVRYwrawfm28hBZyKV1mRoUB0stLC2Tqgs2nDdP7gZo2ihcbW1SJ0P9JCyxYuI0jO1dMQnHjf10yk@yUP@0rMQpQe@oI5bLkERYVyzol51fpwj/NCm4CTwxx3zTBRWMh1vhMdvtPUZDogX1dGhDPvX9iahP4MdQNsNpi7BaGV@Gl4NWtVh3@sFw8CDfRqGcJ/yiIePM3rEDuuNh3chXfdDCR0jU2cWPXN8GQ7Dhu9aL1k0QnOFE3@UMc0UJuNZ5YrDRNDJORoBRncvEn@PkjHSdJmX61EhK@5/SvZ4Bbv4YNkXhUWFWaOPAOQAV05YULAP6YQckwzn0@JchstvZTBwvBQ54dkPWOzFMH4NJCI1TAxjhcycWYLZCNyZPYjxWWea7VAMwjEGWvJ3fbyVJszQ56yHt9zCKPIGLQW2RGEzbxRlLcoU4xDiw@xhcq@9@pOxBwR@AP3Ci0XcsogRaIjrqmhLIe9XZJRRwIXMAwMao2kkhlEs6MEs1I8BbU2TUOPJs4eoQZY/sCiSYfbmuBIlMgMbH7xBLtOCIac1s3FSWRbLNsXtwCVIZZLJP8yw/vfsZ0n4UYnLJ2c4MFUl5IyB9EOkagOV8ELPhHmtiTLHVP6@xKytPbbXEgQsLTI5My6uzaTUyoU8UAKeX1GtNRzDYJxKUE@aeiyHk@Fo@ZHUe3DsWBiZbRGt27b9XUNgZrYSTJYrHSJtaYaPs6KVxCfBNHGKkaUZ8BBuX@lZs3mSiNNSC@Wt1Jp9hw4P0Syym9KTiu7vDss@Toq3aNGrJhotUoQ7Bikt6u9nLWh46@ERRMLk7VWLRowWDhmtGT8aoBJk0lR6PIWI@yTuCXp0gHJYbwdoZ/bPg0RNGsmpkKcqKRbkEumJgdvRaRPGpVEXjS8wTByvcPUgpRec0@yMVHmF3CUGGcYEBoirYj8XnUPxCW7UWQk@otsBupkWWgsVcCSCp7Jp4aCD/muCUVR@ebgjLR5as1zhosiQphoS7Coo17cgKX9zeD1rTQnKHClAxBeQQrdobmy6enyrfrQtkA8gcGlKlpa@@Sw2xhargA38M5NaU1wDR1XJkjGJigtCi4YGkAXYpfT6Pm9XcfUXjJnj0bpBihFsIPhzBn9WZQkM572R19TGItPODLPYktwsbbbIlblIxFD8juSXoshLXdq4AgCfMYbypQJAwLCmhD0qBSj0jsl5MURlH0HBUgHFEj5SVNTIznNBOhJVZni5buTIL8rx2oSRWwgEFhaL80SIwJplcZYICkx0C3Excrxa3J4oByyIFe8zxaErZK/Eaah7jgkIj4StHlHOCiKblxxMiS/X7Vii5m9KfZ03UvPJVKCPxvAsV0imbuZjqbFq19biRWMlgR62WWssEUhhmwjrUeHH/sg1xQx5rm1CjU1GbJUh7bMHuJW6w32b86@h2CanbLXGUPBMz3C1/WrxFSuxoOzfDsAuZNz/4o83VhmmKkTkVQEUlk75umR4P0gL1hTO9Ngq3OiqQHs6PoHa0g674lNzby8W9fVypuyMrv3xej6fRx6@NGPfK9NqPEkKhm48t9u96ffd0d1P40@XLg39eK99PxxuqQ20Dz0CMhE6w3GPL4ZAHCAr5s5JP1bc6t90u@YNDKigxL6DXuOcMhiCoPkn0DYvn5p0/kMg5fz6CzYQ2/eL0MJ35/E6U0JRWigojRbBtymlPAPy4IcummdrRRUBw3FZGTPBtGWXyl9wAsGLTaizKHqx/SWyTk699/v9YVac4H3BGCjgyX2ywN6eWSDPWVDBSM69NyGFo80K/zboG27FmMVkdQSn5iV1zYQKC4@h8Y/8Xm06yqTOPqdgVoEmr2IzVzE8dVakeilbxop/BFjmQ0D7UbmvvVGmTXRKZoaZXgpw9AQYvShkF259YllsOhKTNPt@biTqYnQditUATbdpKaBC2VP3UkseyK6JmzqfFrpIwzzDkDhhyJXHlUBPsz9vVLyddLuPGxTpFgDu2H/6gEgqAJJAKX5ATwyi/S85EOu9RDwRXt/gXR3z4w4WaGEBy3rWLv12l6lUKmJptLoqKpUdeMjlRGWnInbxw86O2IX3HXx/XlpbXy/ymLtrf4GPO@rjvdgBGHTAudq@Gu/CK6SV0G0MjbWxi5fc0lK2uNQqbZeLoXtW2UGvfnj6@7//59//47/cinz5H3zZoZezzzqT4zjuUvvL0vP7Ir6f7V4sL12eLY0ulntF5LJ/UNDwYX2S8yLrUWd8aaV5FjC@khmp2mZT8BlZVKhL/a698a8wumyJdDt00/JryBdH0RibbvvGdx/dKC9hB6/uHEju5AGJNACd4Wk89E7bR/s7mG@AkoALmoFyeVatqHN7jAajM2ilSloG4qEl662PLi1RIAV0xYUZKxcMQn@AB@C3tOTl5lmWB7/BpCX51/38IeztDKdi5TwjVvJiJStWUin6KWy8hq/2khugcy5ng91AKpWFlEizgFaGIgxonUfbB7pqJ0Fuy1qiG3sQkopSQZnZCS6rN3/kK8P3rYU96wlemSn4hIR0TFgk/WVpcA/d8gVy3Kdinja0UGjJTQxVZihUdP/iCsgL2Q4gqvmaCbI1hCpR0UcOyfjkqi@yry26TIgAI1mP3u2R3OMHmIuWBtLkObaVwluOyHqev@LcWGRfaEIbU7j@CAHSp/BuMk@OhMvpZYuNvI1WUjPZCdtsn2Q@NnWY@RNlms6F/k0YTMDG3CbhlgbSrUXacbN2RaQCrV0xqkolTb@FZRS5vulPgpH0VqDaUaC@6NruWZKwRwkQw@GQ/VvzEkbnBCpQVKJb@K6smegMseksCQPpmQ4dbDusODKI4H7OgGx/Tci27ZKTiGIH5gFCSlvydb2gH8qgK2Mids8bX@LlgF6X7lObsNqMjvPwktQExsOuRtohyGRxHskzNCU9Gnu9ay8r0gfD5tib1WHagpXPpO3Y0EKMwIRIoPDJqhc1TyHMLZJdQhTRTSHDIby7oD@Tt6Nx36a0ywl2qRIFGXUFhSDGTkRJ/2usrxJ0jLj6D3SCifLc4K2VkXKIpZEXDY0kpJTpNUNiNic6lqrBlB0tOCmLUdWSqXhBFrrBifaa9L4wkvcxRICsOyWdAKUnwsZrrB9np54/8GKT06hvKT9/tyh4XkR5ppso2RjJUhefFqIL7xArWEd@jgeB4LlJRTOynmQyT85DeZtb2pxHKMa3NsV3PRHo@@fo/jJyDBHHg4AHy8QMFV2B4Yg6Gf4DhG7f6wF@sztvhqx4ns68eeraZ5/PBxcrmfPB1/PfbcJEDslqls2JtNRlqxFLygrMjG429qqM0kIVafB8EM9wPhDswmKQABBxM2ef3YuvLiB0nsZb58/TTJBYlyEm7rfrcxG8O4dmOo6Fm7ae2Cu26vzMm4ItYG6lX@xD/mDzL2ChNpV0Sg/7nHEXQJGb7m837HESuptr@ZdrhZewE@r509zYv8H5NhfeXPpTWEqEuJ2Fqef89xg3xAhxPw29InycQjv5VhN2PQmlj5IcQqWYUz2WZiso4zBPQH6gMkVLRQ8XW@fxUPeIJoJZASyn8lIoKLYcNLgvg/NnOLzGerwQx7WkcwhzJBoZsIkInaDmELK6e@UhDrWVuCyTm5Mjqhi6lYBA97ppY7YYDAc5uVizneUiLqLRaaa/md/MJ2V0TkRjErokF1PLT0Wh/ObV3/778Lf0JF1ec0/G8DtJ/5be2EzzIzzA2wv1dpsup7cx28Z9eubCHhgeX/3tf6F8@SeAgymzbfhXXlewNmbpcq5ERb6myxvwUFhbg3r/769/hTYs8Y4Nr2JdamUFIVZUFKl6A@JdSBd1bCVvS5ejYYX8shAGGxjC3hxe0C5quraZp1O6tDSquPVl4CtljiKneLLLmpClEJ9kKHMKWBlxgRJWkGOQyoKiKwzTDWW1gcwboSl@eeZshLAD@EVac@gqteXGsxAthpZ4WwQdmOEaYT/PD@X8m5S27thKKZOSolpC4tZOjrWbL4r/Dw)

See also: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170701044217/http://www.canonware.com/onyx/index.html).

There are two other languages with this name: [Onyx](https://github.com/ozra/onyx-lang), [Onyx](https://github.com/nxsf/onyx).

Onyx is stack-based. Strings start with `` ` ``, end with `'`. Comments start with a `#`, end with newline or form feed.
Onyx is purely interpreted, code after `quit`/`stop`/`exit` is not executed or processed in any way. So I moved Trefunge/VTFF code to line 14 and inserted
Onyx code after the first form feed.

Perl6-Rakudo, Perl6-Niecza and Coconut treat vertical tab and form feed as a newline. Perl6 is fixed by moving the start of the block comment `` #`⟪ ``
above Onyx code. Coconut is fixed by hiding Onyx code inside `'''` string (using the fact that vertical tab is not newline in Onyx).

Onyx code:

```
#...␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''...
```

Answer (score 2):

## 310. HTML+CSS (IE 3.01), 14404 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:8][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
*{+color:fff}:,a,i{color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
+i,: u{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[os]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4od""n;z cop>s'0}e}eq67+?4[0][ ] 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKk9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vq9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrdGGrs3Y3dN28saaUlCX7uj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d0LcE8z5lgX7MBp2W2AxMbumeXYb6wRuGUYu2/13w7ejlnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeypCR@dSeuMmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2DOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1zijMokuBscfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@2j3yafX/Osp9qkJSA371vRa9LrOntvWqH09hME@P3nw4Lptmn2mug57cBMlPcN2J2P3YHwdfpbtdi3HZIZW1Izrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD2wR5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILL@xxT4MAJy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@x1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mZNbtwR5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQma7bzUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@4ue5QiUbKeL6Xg@t0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwhOhi1x7bR4QLt0WvTIiytNoLan5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4pyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@cFT5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@4/uR9l1YCM2qgpBSStsEvGWMR3ZOdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttjHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2Z5wBS7dtnKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SriQoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3HCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9KzXE6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKYLBPTQvbDmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDmwiR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOUe6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSfRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurEz1nPHSwmjYuXgyDpPRurgP6FOYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrngPWdp3oOIByMYLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyTVCadJ1QnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjrM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUgWoY91XNnsDjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@sYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyW5OBr0wI/jgXJ3nv6dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qju6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrN4QNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gVdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzjIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92I3rwcX4tdvkl@lnA4KW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSY3kw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@TUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4hbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4GdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Rqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfwuSOJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMe6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9HriFH702a9vR6M6OFltorTzo3R6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPABBczxzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vY/cK7JBpBmdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abK3ID1GTJ3uUWhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAT@QEhRQBotkUtSfaEFKHncjdYZbThzqHmAxroEo7DJQ0aECiBEyNugcdsseN4SWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsK2Hl3u9H0UBSg2eNlBARiTZ2j8dYNmIKpBc9X3FsQFsCTq1U2eW4N4ISR99XEngCskoOcrJPWJHPT@yzSft6RjtoiZ5kLHWgK9mtsVyWoPLnpaGyjqrRBaqC8h9FqiLzYngCfYN5yRYzVBbeRpaHWm9FoBLK4RhiIHh1KYl4UGE3Z@i9WasvVAJugsLOpVET0D8TLfVAECWETuAX2hsllQPB4sDhsKe7Jw8roixyx2TTdkoLFn23ZfbJehO9y37YRwf3jnaPvt5YAqNvN0vXLZJ2ppDDqnYyVbvOJJnRjNJmGMYc8P3GetgYcNGPLAlnprrTkKo0a0HlMvXJeXj02XWSgCaE5KAYwIz3NZWG@wGlS2qaXu9aJcy68ThEGQTx/TL1gPkwAwOiju6mj8/TyZs3mHnXkRoKe8SsPzE5AN8yeeD44TR0vKaA@U7NDq8RKSxoobaD/Z9zU9inj8@nqDVfR4ZU6RDLfHr4YP@oQmB7pndm9fsqeUl6Y9ClzFFbA57vT9qWtMwPiD8wtVhcmyOO@jThupTArdYCged5y1bABwDYxNFcpvYHftK8HuC@dz1tZKu2Ag6gb4JwXa8M60Otj0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhXlkFVktrrMB1sdpqZbNWPlMMV1uteZztMNABKcW26@uNI3A681S00eZapFCrBfrHj24g7pESCU0B1cfM6zON4vL6ErZeVJtFveQetNDcvqU9J4knM1lJJqN@x6fW8qjNGfK/P7XHsZTC37oCfiH23d0D477vWXTUUQcGNRqwCY4106iDAw0tD3jEcftu12VbEIZrh36EoDatTOZu13Vu5JCJlpjUCI5cgPzF/hpzCHWN/YYajhQq3Fzlox6m412AlNZzaSQSUYhAJcm/9so8N4Fc83QfH3xjHyoRPZtKBeYUXUCCUBgiF5paIVuyYCpEpAl8liYwGMW4Udp9BzU0jICJFoIuCLg7d15qSRJTSy71vxSlr7o3KP7KnV1jLbDhrAWGEMkOnjx9dPBk//HuF6djI5td@M6kijkgHMTXBF1I63G6YWnd4kUTk4XgIlA2Rli8QApMoIHid4dPvBEIbg29aByBFVzDx39iX3V7TtRTrifmAl3VV06Ls9BjLHzcqwgIDe12HxsjIz5shvU58k9vPB56pWQSSnlv0tSg0Zp81XL7ZjdJ4aBi6PeTOjZdDg6xX8NbFgKQ8WYWD8H7tEB1mFHHodkfuNB4oaE4FA0sxsFTZ1Xf7vagLYzjddZI0QIOptQk29BCgLZyMkgbCWD6AtqKt59PMmftr@hGgfO1njIySdn3tlD8we9Gx4KmUwxqKyCFcu2Tnd45vcNmIKUR0nUgEaZtiSEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9HqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDraljD4yILe9wkkNV17cXrq1EFBP71DuOFAWG1Wr@l1pcxuBtkS/pUycO9C8pB3fQvgXTICa9KbrZBnbfOmOGubVLraLDkeDEWdow7Z411QpN64IK/bVrjsYYBk2DG5teA3iZ7fJZd0CPUxqIQPpFQSChTUtMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQBs3pvB08GHn0NyBBvdyPe2G/Worx71Guwk9YZAROpjbqGU9rB/cAy1Y8D5KKUhc1FIswsrit3npsc7KSGQGHT0w0NbLYBAnfFBR7QTDLYCE1Aoap6D5AC@wt7S3ryXERv9wGkQIeGEnQ@gQTg0aNAFOQOBeUJ2eUJ4TGSzmKQzx71wEFrTYgW1aY95H787GeFgnt0Opw28pw3uB6BR4kJynUb9mlaL97LywJQKaASabGANXOxKAO2KRIFFSTD5iCG2BT3sqIZilVJx4ATgq@zuHkixlsX7i9QBNqKApfZZdDxK7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVJn43PIBNmX7iE4B6IoMRbOolET2gpJ24A/L0nPpb0PGer@5Kw9m4BykGDpPNiju0nOttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sMrqxsREtRavRBJh2wLSNph00xcG0QyaVTOhPQxOFSJAJXWsUAu3q0auaD3mq1JEHpqg5vLGHMbNWKqXrCbOmi7eBbwWyAigPvlV8AZyoUqmgUVHk6gUO1YD@Hkr7HvLOcWtkDwUJvgoKAf8WNEgTEaB5j9r8yCpj23Q9RQaVETQaLVQxY6PoaS11Wj@9PG3HT6@iCQytlM0KtA9BeI1jA607cidDUNxqmZIKsk2ppUv1crMSTUW3YrGC2oeITEX5pKDETU7rWNQCnoqdnkaBpII6tVZvRPCmCUNRAkIBHh0bWhn9fiyqXRYg/qZSV@JRCKtEEyCWK9Eo0KWFRPAo0dgjwJnogT0FUkLBhCouPKZAApLGpLC4fsMa9majsIeg1w20bOxBnw/GQ2EgKR6Wkm94@LBCt9DS9/Ve7g@UW@y8Q31pOOPSXeKYniYXJob49e652hm4YzP5uQaNJi1UXUY3oklVhZqQXDgkSvZj28MibDqWO/HCPY1LO0AxdrA96U1AWPqzZhLAVfZQslo9l0U37wJ0FgzzYFWCI1YqH/fyAbRbGtwoRFErwcES0C5oOokNchGnmvBeGZ2Q4KLH75vP5oavtSC2MoVhKYzI7jruyFKBJBBCoskfNFVIqjIxo@SAer5ujEsIV6rSsOFtWyARH/Rdk2jLxXVoPGg4CIWH9jkEObLaUh/kRwfEo8bzYmS1k1sSDc66ox7UEJAalMRGkFsD4ZB0vWFbG08hqBTDCjfsyFt3oHResLZhGLlWtlPy3ZArgNg9yCRslTrQxPWdVB0cFZHJ@7xbyG@jPzm8v8/7TqiyxeoV@9EaA7c9Ab1StJuOLKebYPvAT7bjDmwggx/@zVn/yHXHvJUPH6t6Znij2R5M@ib1@VzvllkbruU23T51Ba0LOvc/GXlm3@SdUL7r7uePQdd/dnJc0UohT0nzfLA2buyHXB4tp@dBeMyRhln94SGPM6a8mZWx3vIno6GYEQ45dJiIqWiQR759Hu39IoVjKMK@gPYDnIYGurLoRaDPwFJ4LJJHnJqGM3qE5aWeukL7lW2wwJ9O/rjiOMf2UjfI/nzc6SxYp8n6TEXR1J9bZ8iaT1FbaCOGUcpyTzhfbcFPGFCO/ATT1q77E8IrmGLQs/r@COIRKCY4SgZ1ex/VJ2iboCbO545ZoEgPcTCEJDQOsbEW6JrejW4LKFNDlfuWIhtUTqAOS6LmIm0mmejiLlNJcVwxNOlx6elC0556T7arfMAam04j3mpL8s73zQaA2K6W/dlEq7xhTNFo4I2gEm4QgpJJw/Y3khpMwvCoT12iIGXJS0KrYWqk1NNpfr@e9IgIHSafnk4/SRlfQOMD53xt3kl2rTJGt5Ja9M37oVs9EBssPl0kGeTDxOm4/bbKB70g/xlvLmFGiKkGwawzEvhgY4/8CWc2TmIREwNBXIbmqt2Aey3rqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyyt2eJ87esBjXYueYN@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@ZZlPBBaUIHeqaKAlhSkji5jCLpGYREoDqcjevkULmW0ajNhAxhnDnL5XfpsW5OMjF5B9JGZAh3UOEhpiegqKjlNJ9htvi@O/6MIbBsnzazqvei6Hw3Gd03bOXBpFCkyNlKZnUc8MQg/O@jdDdmyvR48FrwEO3K@xCjtv0OzQY4kHGkwRw/RkQd30QsOG7DSTR/SiHvslMS9OTVmItml1Jk6XxjTRzNTXt/hUiwXy3Gk27VVegQg428x/L/EGshJLnqFlNN0vPdjBA9UiyE/eJpon/fqsJrZAd6ikxhBKvP/LN9tA/5u504P6CvszA0MDNAXMKbWzMrNEUPygx/KM5d3uk75tEmHIdBvIljmCJJn9wLAcNA3tqyroGwMcqBA5DryJD9BF17AZx5yPM/rv5ZEsG6pzQG63Vvm9NsuLR0WDStBcbBMRuM5lWxSIhCzPBGvKB3ZCDXcUuLcj5U/FYsTMPN97k/GEP0EdvjUT7SHe68qm8JnKmk3dggap2bStNVk@Ms8mbVcdnnUDtTi3xO889TSyrIJWIgaZG2hcnnyewJHdheref6/yNq9fkxf0uo0rPGfiDdUmte3b/IsKwmBNDKM@f67yYouVSoFhNdXsPj0@kBMFdGAUMcciiTNY1RDR7Gtk7pvNGapCvY/nsmC@AkicSiseT6VXDFgPh6vDY/uUwheLy0NPtRanx7KehySfJavyvjlKsJg3e0uuQnVlD8y@arRDxpXCfNl0hxteg5FSCmOd4zjR@dKcm1MfK6TWpG@O5qY1LD7Hwx@cWNXPLaoNUZZbbt/2sED3V0lNf87dPC6cp0yP0LwKexkl29AQxXpcDUzLpYDbGuNc1BVs9QEyjc8BxZm2IT7R3FXEarkXeK/UIHrQGObP5ZXam6VYfYB8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@HVC9uz6LGcsGdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8jbM9u@967Jie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8f5QIRcIKV2/RUj5GpDr6OK9UrSfJUdnt2UQrf8a4cTZkHFNLbtMUolBndWpg7YBjgguT9mDVIFCakneh7giYhzLuTBn/vsXqD1WkdavPYYz0qhBwcMAxQIYxiOuZf8isWXWx9b@MKF0A2z@tkSEMvesb0F9Rc8bWcqMlP6RIfRU6sNFVKc/sSbW0rbGYfOVhcuI17QzPhyplEjGphgCwFEHXPMS@HojGocfhDVW1fi1VpiY0Gq3btdmFoXaEBTwIbaen4LhKRpuhug6k@FCri400Jyj9STrDf0i7bYXsEOXj5VDhVuUpQUV3bPoXtto4o08nHlWyaRSKaHDhIZyFj7WNabSQdhXNn8uREw285jnfnH4bhQyLo@DyBKe27hSBBmr2vbkuVhMOrZjjWf4/EBp2nTd/sfkFAjVto3aGCiXNId3XY7dUHfE6hQ2773wsM@j2VnVb8FrG9G8BPpgu3ldpofHmj4oN1UcTR3gSNfi5/oenNDI1W2x4HJu7Bbis3r7q3VJ0SGiawUtv7bUcQ3VbVp9k7@mucw6eEUtvRbeotAQo8A4aszHiudj/JFrQmk4A2LZbWio9KyBRZ9rFH2z/Wri@a@VnqYu3qucp5bVSk73rdYqD0Mb5IKDz4XB6ZCyNHYdaGKNcQIhNlX6OEVV2K6SwP5w4lIiHwzMrsX3qFgnKed9FjhNh7fs5sblvRclPjWnBcHmPcyrWQIK1Zk18/z3UoCPZy3I18ng9h63a4W/hd2gH1DaV82NvVnFOj235/SsHp@QHnytKhzAj2O@p8g61AHrbg/nyA2HC3Pnw/Tsu/3@h9ATRSMXlK7bWYrTPq6qxSVhHwV3ZjbBQbxu7b8zx1x2oGFlqelZE6iXPHfsDi2VvlZ57WNfD3@ukqH@6Pcv2om0tqkPFPHfvyj8W9uWXdMdD4f0agz7E48eFFSlxdC36U0dPueFZlu6o672xh00NWGpiQkxNOi@XMQ07XGrh4vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9Xh/@@UFtV6SMzdT7aK31bSDvaKYhv1TC7sf4OliV6aIDiVdrgWGNvrKsk47We6tD86zl8Q5RNLES9gmHSiNfFV6i5fSl1xN7PAcamiQV9PDykQk0rMJdTMtYqVnR4ou5GBbTNVZyKSnpqJCrVgoUHn1l/9LCBLpQEUun@WMVQuFUEkahCS8fQ24xqYg6CO1Q1y3YL/DXwmyopZWc05t0vZsCk/fYt0FFw8fqbguaJB3qtYY6y3TEaxWZjX4SV0/CuwE618RaO6ySXTuuQv70vmq6Nrwa8IKsm6zsQ@vbQ48/mdpZORonJklBW/z6kCGnzWx5Y1pkTNvq8FEQNN2mIg5cGqcFHURt4Zg@dqKjMOeKFxdcjtsFoa722dyz73eV2rJ0/tHy7A/qTPWLJ1bXxEncj@wxzgJdwhXEssvmLd0K@2sT07O/NoGUrWI23AqCj0SOwnsG4NcSeI/Nrt16uJARAZKCwGIKKX8tsD9a3cyLi57t4RyqwLCmYwpZjjMxcl0D2g1LfF7vug92wZgXIL6@cqnvZd3r7nCGy9BmZFrXs26PqZdVvFc1HVfNLluLxMVkMJx44rUcB5qlFe6FHpyRvXdhA3D1NYhW1jP74@U91aEuV9DCRKU4N67Sxr9h990u@0YhxUBpAyUMlfMljHMPquenODVo5CzhRIr7A0c@saNDHfGEvYa8tdJMtR17vL43ZzzGaUL@GxPDaw5c@pB8hE/t7sdCUE@WU@TR7br@fM3zLfU7cN6xOxm1LDQGG5mEmwUiVmvPn9aMS0Vc3IjlItxKWzt6A9Wh60zG6mjirK0VcmtrhRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/fqaEuYGmgd@mhVrQ@Jt4/dnctHLOwDUmsx1QxFbL0UXfflviPt936YjmIN8SZhc3h2qRuL7vLmvvPJ2NrPEHN5hA@E8G960WjhzeGvcT97HruFAbDUFQDo4svpnAwlyP5QEx2CNcLg/0ad8azTGBXVEJcW3DHFpNyN/@3PQhdREHfN8cmyuqIuobpPZfYLqVV@x@0xq9ok6/kHlVk3YRoYfWlNoWqxmGl0F13GpxlRj74xbKyMKIjTd0XYc/Sdqm4KU/Xi9VoCqgx4ePlWs4w3@hX2Bp@2wxqYfnfKKI1ea7XaxK68hqun3@XDMtybH5tABzZFte8hFunkB2uQxTQfvy1sqQ/FoZMm8agSZ7bno0Tr@8qTEHqU8/YhZQzxy1XBwJE4Y1E3RCOx7cIqaDRQN87kATCD8FiWW2JmLvxdvQ6g@aA3qsbDCEcvPIauJyoyZtEzI2pzczk/cMiT0SQpO6gp0FfHGFhTrHYk@hNaLcXm0ttKMWqWoP6UGSeuVwOc3XUR3bar0xsdfMJXrN@6YX3CHNySdkXNFXHSpG1IucNGkJ/dKStDh7DRSavqWOeyNo8yfH67q3/f1bloyHTAYWDjIvjsKsVF1dr0eJdZePpwfCdWSpYu9AkCXBPoJcP1R3V2qeCB7@h/e@moRKuJHL@HuagOi6fQQfkJ@MHPH6EA586nrjjj09BLxx3cEqcYLJykIQePGSgaatVYmA3HMmfd770A1NvRq0qTmm0v61qtoncT22VMs5V2mHuenNFLl8NVlyFzdDHVttVWywgCMN6iN/YVngTbyXDKCGZSPO99STnLDTXEbMAF1G3AtfMoC@5Y7VoUfv5NB7evDo8EQbevrS@mm3h@sxbuhxCzs2GIVUqEvqlTkKjXfyGWlt2xsn7x3r6t6jAw09rKA3H9FQ4YUjcwuvlf2eYutRM2mubAWhqzVeriA@PHn8KD5f@8lie72RO7CUsPPe8XEC17Z89Xipczj0AygdHXe6MvjBvq4rS9j3mUOjg6uk55KYVkE6saA1Csz4kG/4cqty1XKHVvtkNrQ@h8oTJbj3gdHnVibyiXlud7EUsuJKQlFBZUUtl1FCk7OhsW2Ngveq/DyzhygtW/RK8tfK6SioOaSTo/Ry7WHdiP91LYalxEyEjwukp25y69hWoWR0e2hKmt7fFzFd11fR@djsQL6y7MrMWvSwbHy4755/wFCyJRovamCljoGrVPvWqeR5dQCiO4kP7J4XlmBsrpwGsw5AYJ1bWuAvLGdmOiqNZa1TL0oQGie1rfXyDesDBqSCGT7nuCH00jG@YFY9i7XIqNwS8ckoFGRv797BbQGOBC3X@/r0yTP21PRwd5P1HsMYWx@A8VwzeqVivxVurbdyOLU9AlDGWnjd4fLyXGLH5qjtOrPp7YNwtLgVq3barDiAhV/kyerbU3tZXdXi/VpPl08zui1uvo7DnS3oweFdbwSg99/5Z7qeStGeRvjWU/zzlpzxCziLocmc4UZ5YaeTg0A0tFBv0cBCWdoafWRNcToK7w1e1qhfWr/l1tR9eWV1dbLOrbDGLbMmvhtuaMnSWorXnHyB0dHECW956yXEpgV8XSBfqeVp/r7EsZgTjyvK4tb34XVpfEUWbozGF1OB37dv2YZYMwUOwTIysVIL908CBc7C9Y0SgcAFdDGnUtGzRbaDG9CXQDwrFCNYlfg2NX5kNbZ5KVZAlUr6Fa4Ck0syEyvUgl0n@c6JABj3fINEMfVMZ5tjcNn0108x2vubvWWk80Elo2dT8KUlwwtay2JhGeC0efn04On@8cnuybPjWqp@JSti@STHzXEgNn9h7SfptgyJF3QDXuL7qNICzD5ER/uSo67o@elikLJrSassJG2eKHkHw2xeOk4ySesIk@oV4KfKPDZyhYoBrThsP8WUQWIZaIkvv@sTSeVNDlqmOCHTSiy1LOKh6XmQLOF@/WQEcmXpNLryiMXWl1CCu67bFjF6Frv98mN8sHvw6NnRPvMRnHPNhd0e9yrFLN8ZFeWtakE@dWyaklBhUREkCnlVqUQfRIEwUS3KSrR6k3YlBUYHbz51cN2nCL3FYpsEHygYDTIl@V@@mbyKaji7TgG/UR@pKBOURw/sBFdk/dlP2nzXbn8fBv/4j9GAhAutd5fEassVay2RolQyh6sPAaFdsmlZZbA99/xgFYk2bQeuvKAtlK5tr6PQjhf8RBex@5EfETGIv9MvdtPgTkbQxjy3cU0lx6GDGwstsjKO7NJmWhrbxRNOgOeZSTvHA@oTZ8w37xBL/SPAR1ogURJsk5Dl@8zLIY/R7Q1g5abVtR3mOaD7WuMSewV8hl0hJb6wV1Wr0RtBfND8aBu1Nx70Qx5v7ETkJU/Hyfe/9t1kt8zAPE3dg69fEV8dMP8qN79IYl7f3K1oHn8YCdxhTGDNIw9ojvQOHebi8AXUc2Lhpkq@qGT2ALLmnCiN3nkM/KmChJ3DidU@h4wCFoNcEguneXzWqB7DLc5KySSyEQ4raTRZ1JrymRvXtjrLZXMZPQlIquc@QNqbuIur0jhARSkB40vn9rDysgnstb3NZFSlrEquzHMzuem8SMsvA0Q3wa900UPkagzCQJB5CHCrimBQn8R1BYOiPIrqURRFbRcqGnLHCgm/HUEImcWAWJxGFm52O8VTfcajmb9lXxNPygntW78pAKk6VDNkUmRJrPV94o6BZRZWOfO1vjhziVdquBeWx0@top3ykAe1m6VpvkTN3yBflC8Nyz0HlU5drx/DeSs/RxDHCKIkL2PZ2gt2Oj516knOmwzY9EeCZcPM7ID5nyS7K3iWp3v35j5pseu7nCGx2N1jx0Wd8QEkhsWMpJFO6jllnqRMZmmSRIpENJAc3L3hLUQHognERMuyX7lDb3dv/@Crh0@Pb@wFRj6j172BJK9ux09VLVGrB4ZoOFmLWXLvQfL48b0HfkbMkc6FJDCoLyIl@rqUzJuCCHI@tfh60pZheD11qzF@ztcfXsc3baxDjQLdwENPfUS8NL1PfUCT9K9HbhSWUSubXYfSHF4yBHqPr7C6gWpMubyq1berp04kepMTlhSEFxFtCwsBmE69rc0kMvvNxGHCgtPlTvBcHC9cFtPLy6K8mcYtaXCN59g9m2/GIyxCDqH0@tGAiJS0pO91Zek75Gr3fMsog59@xzevCW/ZEUI4l1pH8RCoE/8gPZQi8w3vxF5vPWiQ9e2m5G@Vwvd887emCrZ749ucxBRJbJvOI46Jo/WmpalGY/kxBaUdwUqwddvH@fAUCQo06mtPJ9AwfOoO@Ta6NGZz3/JNRy6I3/sTPvhrsa9OBuCvQ68ji/rPQHKrEBgoGQ1Q5foTSAmxe9w0jvvzQXw13ENOJFwbtLOxqaL1rGnb7oJsjykJkGif6HqdBTvMYaJpRzknKlOezXNhbVH8FNfNhcn@UdsMTucImDVTs522NY1FL6JKqQ7xo3304vl5VJGX8RJtdyj2/2tf3/cwQD@vr5ck5liUTn9TwWXSoli8KSXA7jpgvmGPf4ZHsaj1PImOYqqgLn48Hj0CI6gRsc7AHLLYxOGbGmmMPmOnMSdBu8CoVb4vmsPicWoiwYscNEYhO2Ti9XfMdGYslqwAE6Ct57Tx9cYespquaXUwUyQK28SzdfZA48INQhQJmrUQpERgK8hC0HAAjHgh0TiDQxh0l3DflhFtDbXEmY4aoW4GF2lCqWbVOyx0RNKi5igXiyWRoYtSsciA@26KQy0JYG/IOV@XB@qKDQiAZtCg1aTIXJDflHgRijfCEXkodi4AdCKhvQz9DQ0YwJrvNNjqjfCO7TtQVnAPltKzkweNgpKUWbADQndkt7EbjG/HGzTaxAEKUEyTC16jZd5G@xSD4dZWDb7FAu689IAKjHxNpEbCZLh@YOicN3V9LdeLgCIXwGcGKwCxTKThg8M93PwBySVuy4X9z3@OR5LKsc2dXLrRP49Hs6kyPPRylmXZJ5unqrpZM7Kpyt3NummOT2VmJjNb98@tXqd50E2eyjJLs0wyuWXkXp8N9dzWi5r2elqXa4VK4qz@9Iw9ffrFu8Y7RZ6ez@TTGMtH2N7hW1mHBERKeVZkeC@96KzApdeaVrocBbinp3jUqJyXk8latA5/cnoJF/dUq2pVbaf@7p1Sy0OaprPTCJ7gxw7vkjO1k6iryTCUY9u2k@x06LXbcLs9Vudn0Eb4FY/HVCYs1Bq3Y4Nph@ymu1a3O9k3Z9zejkzw9WAswj7@xvPnz9HwnC725kiE59CZH0epYWYjzEgZf/bTjavE5dPG9p99a5C0NvB1iK/vXj1G87Ge/WRj45N79zKZBFCJm59@4@nXd3d3M/cT2ae17E5GTW1s/@mfbGwYxraR3Kh7nl6P1s7OvpCNVEbW/uzH0cbTp1/zPMwWvNJMByM@C3DrqFOdsTdwnXUY/sn8ph0ym2hudt4wI/ImAmwdmdGvEWG8FFZISwpfG0yv7uT/6/cPX0fGkaqRfD6C9zjyOpIrRLgRDPCV9r/OI9XINnrLXUVmyUqlAsb8f/13EL76VYCDLrNteFSzPqzcLFJVKxTkbaSaA4NuGBDv//XNb97S7XOX1eCSM3lD3qnDtUXXtoT7TqmpZPKad71wR7/DmDPujS0XXzZ/OfBiZtmBVvdRLR6P1zUVLq1BgZK6bpxSh02Ytai/JRJYlxm3YSG7OZ8IG3B7HiGeAqYivuJmYUGsxi2eX/f3fMlVfv4PfR1JkdzGXet@tQqi0KgaW9U4XRunpRInf5LlC7Lr3sUereipHGUv2SNB7KqcKhhyIpG428ADntkUaapOI3MCMk4jFlmgbITNv1jYKsL8YGzu52P97eP15//bn//gz79Pvx/Q/R9xiy6nbXeSWxz58yq/WLUqV0fy5Sl93GWpUqFUSDbY1Wlsq1atHzE99enbaDYdPcY0kid2qvg9nJHgqlbx4aOBX9UIt6ly09xOuFSDD/IxD7LcHxOSySdqBKpgMZNJrZ3XOW4cv5tX7S5kk2zki3K9amSNQ8g6XaaMK7LepsfciEjRDlwb8KM/XDvYeSxs8LlBltyFvC65NgJUbr8WsJQitVqybtVBkWVVH8jdjdJGoZQrGZApqwGXV4GOnIeliZbXCpoB4uNdbYMdcV6vs7h/ncZvvZ5pWkMYyeDiraruNCJF/gGuqsQil3DV323V3gHriqhropzGt9V6NS4wgpfWuFuPq1dXNe1FvFwW/@1qYCzTxU2QkPqVqm6/AFi1m1A5UHpqjRfbADa@XduuuHt0aw0ksVp/Ua1tL4YVwe/ejaOMvQsAqpt1Fs240Zx7lynx@KaqbtRWpgEA12OgBGxDBl5tX1WvattXV9vb8N@m55V4g@3V9o0/vebXCj9zdyo2p7Vk9TR5KtimDt9asoo2WvIUDFV4gz@ohqQIKCZTKbLFtiJDpufTYGJWSd8y0sns9JPcPqhGtbqKLZiKWtNz2brKJdVLjZVUvq@3XsgpGoqihttp4FI8jb2UIi/ff/m/4H36/svfx3ofimVRiiS3sHlQ5K0EeDx22OPHj/F@7Djwh/sxvxy0QYvHaOfwh8N9@H4Ca26DxQGEApONQk5uxPWZwSLbci6PYuGXblzRaPQfvTSK@ShvQeOStZceWP7Ssusf/dKqS4q8LWI5b3mMp0mKULmHvIDyU0XjJT6ar/H36A3@Xo/xd9LC39Fr/LGTN/g7GuOPPW7i76mHv5PX@Ntt4u9kgL97r/H3eIy/Z138SZEKaNubO6l@qpXSz/QzMNgsNWKpXqqnt7EpkLJYapaasdTA1dtgsuCXApOd6rBUl6WclKPr4AiGMUuN0dSBVxd@HYAygp@No9ZneqrFIJY@AOVn89D7LUgy5VSqQRtSfmmBXqzpWkrL2XXc0bwm141igWlIYq1Re3kareNWmUYxw5oza@P0JYt4oFOXI8nT0yTvHWBGpoybn19dNRr7T@43GkmURaeP3cP5//BwEP5c@x8cuo8P3YEL/8PDw8fMqsbvxtW7cFWq8W3x2olUyzunJRULri8rIsntndNqWkVzLg7F30C7@Edec4jwrm6cSlEGqspFmRSi8sV5@aJMhuATDI1y4EF44wawLAtFCmzKvkZ1Adf5BVniA40Xz08DEzckn1@cYsMAWnzBHzTO8Od/g7/9/67/42csVquDghO7vNqO0aXgT1Eury6vxLOqxGLiI7YNP7SAbwxyeVVFI3m6BFMtptSVqytuB8@Yss0BVjGO7SoFnnuE0h8J4qR4@SP23/aNcYvrFDfVNudD9aen01RKKTf9TXxxmMp8SyOmSpmOZNls1vT6n/6YtmreUchTNlMu61uMfxgZo1zO@F/5Qrlc8D82Y7Hizaua2tFzoOFkMopSLsPHjg82BZ8B2AKA9T@yANXyzBaV@3Lk8uCQNjEGMZGNKJgiLhhiKdrrHI/NiMol@c6dmDiOc2dXuXPHKKbevg1shkOw0hesGo22PWo00D799q3ckGnovJiF71Th7VuQZVHFHcWe4GkrEFFM1dknRpXiLLojIEQenJmeNOZY9EzPHI9HsTf2MCHj/BtPVugwhFTKHZ1Gf/a9b33rNFqpyKpMthkdAWAsLLu9nctUq7kMmHMFoJS8ecnPBenGi7pytZmUOTWYvBmNCCe9kFe4bIyiO1RxbKcKBdzDi11eRSjbWSarxEC6KqBpXUXwx631YpHbs0wuVogXxa@yobAqKAH8hw3UdDyzld@6W2f0my67UCSXL62KflW5tErYz3dVbomj7nDBnnXnTroINC2kyqdSo3F/92S30ajIsoz1ITzQkoS7hCfsDEfRGmV4tlivYfrqp9FoqXyXmEMvZFkkWhb@1CjUEqxQJDJIdgdX40LaJV20/jckg974kERn0AZY4mn0bH4/fbS7t3@SMLZBpzEe7O4ljONn9yI6fmbn3@Scxu@j/d37h88gwNNH@7vH@58efL7/7CnYe@xifvkSWDzn77BpyfcFey69Gr0xLcu0JpbVuJhMLl6zV7bdsIGw/Ylt2253xDyrYVnWELz5Vxnulu2Zr16ZoyFd7P2PvvP@R//d@9/53vvf@c773/nBz778wXfg/gnc3@Pv7/3bYhafP/vyn/3u@9/@HbD8j3D/Edw//dmXv/lNftP3H8P9n0N2fyzukD9@SwDrV3725fd//LMvf/WHcP9Lcf/w5v1rP11@/@Dbq28M9/3fXe/ne/8O7t/jsHy/3/ttbofvG/5/m/v71R@@/41/z/9/Kn5o/J33v/HH@BAf//SHf/qf33/rPxhG4U//zftvf//9t7/1/tvfff/tf2y8/81/o6fCj999/4M/@Ks//L2/@sP/if4/oefvfcj//Q//6V/8r3/xv//FH4r7p3D/ezD99C/@AzDs3/7Bj/D//T/42z/6Ef7/53/1t3/w63/7K/@aDL/FDf/3v/y3/PnXv/af/uZffPevfvrNv/n1n/7Nb/3BX/0fv/p//uZ/@uv//vf/@n/8Flr@1k//6o9@5S@/9Z2//PY//8tvfbni@Z21zy8/wP7LfwCbD8fzQ@B8SLo@1ubLXwifvw815rEAnwB3/5P3v/nLwOC/wdj77/wEp53CveL/E0MnPz/hX/8fMBg304wuKTDB/evvv/M9JNH/ACSCf0Cv7wYfCy7847vzDyDrv7gWKGKVFivPglGIb0ELY6tYFBVo4LxNIX/25T//cRDFLy9CXXCDGL@LkmrB7bso497/6Jvvf/yP3//ot97/6FewNlMzxcRuQtXX9z5DFahmP8Afesx9iD/w@MUXEP80Tn2lahy/2BfC8YsvvpCmb5M4z/nuW7D9gqz4xbgTuDHh5LsJe5yqGvbDjSnfuInWb8NRIxniGG2cVIEtX0/Jptk0LjCaYlccvsEePE23yDjFJ9mi81TCx/w/N04lFkc//MKjYXwjGUQ4EQU3SlmIJj6d@vQixYlxZYX33E5pGInizRQZpmA6jU@hRQoGiCEOTvfirFKpxDFgheMDnxy1aoERKvF4BdKNoXmYRKOAIKb3CAqErMSPWGOrMuUB4wiv6pMjLqHVkawbcrxQuQ8RVqb3GcJC4AT25ctKtVCZVhHcO06P@DR@j3BCYJX4tPoOvisEM469SvffASqFSjxeLWCEmEiePYkGz6QsJY7SHmdxkQfwpi7au4x9IusFmQ9pbCDBuG98xue@d2iQbQfcT@NbIjn09410bxHBNygqEQvj7jukKu5w7RE9AFxV1TSNwY0DdzvsLjhPOag4RQuvOIcQJ44gDggsgA0xL@KUv3H6gPgjla2PvuJViadmc3NTilTltHxIQzxxaLWPzkr8bI@3vGlUYnKuKKO1RVO/eeqszafU7bB1fwueOvz3N2hGdpyVCa3NKPbuRRmPj30S5/fdu1vsE0g9ved2ElPjaTeDveuY0O14XDYg1qobl16AdJOAfQnQW0mbVmhgKS4lEoxplQi6scPDQ4EaWbyoSHHgfiOt4zeOBEwmkwiE0LSElkiIt0ZvstCEQSNX8dY2kebUG8kMI1OG9k2ZoRULN0d0aLei5bt37yCzaFZG6QBalExM0DAyBXIEC778s9@f@SsHjExR4s1ppuf46dsxOpxPYYrEYmxLkfj8XY6Ef8WiRqEQRZMCeaLFtvz5Ojld8jsJqY8wCMHbeIWs4jvuHbK9w8eP95@cDOt1Jll0aqLVGI7cluV56wRzDMPtPrnPp/cbxRyiEanVMOaTkoFiSdovpUhoHtw/OjguMU4TkUOxAJJSpg5gQYqiLkWGw@fbETGnQcZjPFz5GJ@lefpjRjGNEVbLUqRlYbMEGA7/rCw99rr33Cm05ROynNBz2ERTqAuVSV93S6XKOz2Tl@BN3xOGG07x1alQOnESuLa9TUSTqpcqdXujETI4J1WrYnIQ06Xq8f4JBDg5ZLqR0hi09C8zeSOTzWSNdC6XzRt6JlfM5LKFNNQ1uVTWMPRiJlMsFPNXUvULNtUQVxXM/Urfcrrj3iZOyZFPU3KIHpu1VAJ/RjoNT4CY0LP5@sZG/1JFBE@JLS5xbtUVfF6qSIGvwMWkr0jsK2AFF8SBE6aYmK12cFgWU4ZwH4gYnzck61ko3Ip0CozEwUnD8FUeDqH8QGs/dEuRjW98Y8yqVWhlqwcPpAiIqR7z582odlvracRI7cnIItcuY237cxtPd9HatjfsmzMonClNilxdXXUA0sEDHFSlTx6ijc@rFtk0wXw1NaX///oFr4iqVqXtYRUYcjs5BKMJxsx20gRjE4zZ7WQTjDYYi9tJG4yTalpPbScnUE9I23wXJYaLNCvy2Jripm3cTq56Vr@j4QqBikwRGPK22JWwKsJVcamFa7YruJIPp8jHlEupXWm7LTpRSmprTbc907zxrI9T6fvuqBIFdSzqO9h4SCcuy6rUWF0bukOoNI1sPl7TUyCj8dYLCSORTbRxIv7QHONCi51sqnRhO233Qvvi8aOH4/HwyKIp@juZYqlQr9VkOV4jaHU8h46XQ3VjA1jXMtsqvDuuM/ZUo1AvpVMF6SpIlQT0QFSrEvqMI4oJpMml4OuS4zpQiLYu45SWUqfTuSolzIR9Of@WzEuVf0FCr@JmonkZfJbVkL@4nSixydzxSiqZHahDLlt8tl1JNrIFuVwrz7/zOblcv5LuDqy2beLU@9PU5Y1AuZR8Ffg5TaG3JZ5y6AkSzpMLXMP3j6rSHLEaCLX6PtRVtfq2v7MUcothqEZaTeuqnsb/LQYD/x/u34C/gU8IlTakE1xd@QRkGwhvhz3CjazHLjtxXTqz7J7VWuFjr2fSZLi9ket5fw8/90znjDvdt/mWRoHTQxMPK/AG9ri3wsez4QAXZlqjfzAI@4MmIEiFjDzcg8eo77rLPOTZs6crUvk42EQQiMF3EQTvRwefPjwJvU/2d/ceSjl27/DJ/WuvrPCUZY/2H5wEn3nu6gfNBiC@vv/o0fVP8YpgNY/dtRssm/cNuoSzae9AI@eOMGZzc2MKjc/5Qi/bC2Z38hV9JenEX/1lMizhTYu1@FpZbHXRPhZC@dLzRUkaMse9YPkUa7v9vonnNXY2wLJn4qoWC9WJPh0rilFfuKN@@8JuWxvSY1xAU9TxUDpEQnoIQAaTFi0at8cS7orUxpMUcXigiYfBT/C00hWW8EIrNI7sbg8E84Xre5Capsng/tgLwlvha7zeYszjILsbLv2b3qWIhFqjOTYjhfKdO/rTEXB2tZAqlboWtCuGrlfdnwJ3sQl7BvxujlCsbibZZlbOteQHTGtEzC3Q1Lp2zfXqwyNWwE7rlpnObIHirKPuAdqiaeUjKIpBV2KJAkO9CXXamgF602kqaWbctiw75Tegvg@rXjR1ZV1Zr3P5@E4G6gCoXED1K5f@@l/8BBl8KwmyLKLLMk763dAljXRUo1jIFoppo5AoFAuZrJ7LZhO6kYAmQL4IsaX0gp4rZIt6opAppjOg9IFrtpiXInxGVXKLQMK7BGCdFh6ytk1qrtarShE@mMTexEyFRczge8JkC8LIeKy2N6ZVhVt2RTYyTE8xaOEARJO1WOTBg73UgweyfA8/cAh9LyXLbfzIFlKp/D1Ztshlr4DVtOzyMAXcq0Ie849U6t6eLE84ANzmUZZ7@LGfww4SWbbxY2/3wQOMp4MfBoYHb2fchX/0/Y88eHPwI52mHhZZfh2AA3@7PKIMYbqPHxgnujzgLnvgJsuf@vikUgDhiPvjEB76ad3dleUD/rG7iy57lPAsR/Uz/NilS5aBcbDwyHIXDN0RFFtZboIRi5Ast8DUmplgh0fa4V6AztiU5RknEJJIlqfk22ydyXLDt8doHj58aPbGbavLr9mIv1uAGrjY08n@g@annza73eZotrv/6RG67O09NDuzyajZbYpgzQZcLoQBl7PB7PoFOB40GmZ/qctn4OJcc2nMGhbi1jBfA07i6mIkg8YeuOyBy7JxOA4NrgF4beJ1bwDve2aTXPyLXOg9bTblMjIqaop0Li2UGToiNjEwWyO3jN/TygZj0Vg0MavlUvUyObAB6ISp8hUdSBvDp4ktcuVyVptWUvXKtJI3@ASOTkw@nRpZW05sDHb0Yra0Ye7oRiY@LeHaYrcTZVFV32Ex/c7WGxZ7ouwY6UxJPt3ZUeWaXt8x9EIpl3@xNZFlpYTPnXS@BB5TUWiv4kOp5es7@WwoSD4fN5NGKZ9XyldAjjFUsU2UKo1Y7MIyzxQF0cV2FSSBH4c7o3Ta5U5smphWOF5sppSnFb3Mt6liqRuw2rgn4qQ1dkccYhfATXdSJTpwV9aLBRniTyZjigKSiYQIvOfzs55/7eTs5OQLkFnQYhXtvaf8FMey@Pz04Z4GTUDxhXsZag9QI3dH2h4KlgUXvtWeb3UCQlV7CPUkKO2@Ha73GLl9bX8KrXBU630Hf4cqTewrpJ08XIBzDI1dHjMuly3T5hROy2K41aPdZmalCiazzWKEFTOVC6qhG9VqpVEZ8DNzq0GozxjtgzgHc@Bx3INFvBT8EtdACIdGJXVVblamkSnAaVSYqr8cuO2XRrxVbuMOj/cq9zBwuQHvZtmqWHhysByRy50dp8LYxPHMjvXUGuGS9IPDTaiGcGFErMMsZZOd0jnDe6hQX6nVEXPmmD2ZDGKmWm0qi1ahTyRN7Gt@ki9ppQ6ObF@VOxUWe6GUX8PnaJPF2to9ZSdTbsfusYYCNqmXnZcdZrBcpkxHr8UQEhQiog2d36tUqp@BisMBn5VKgIjI4zOAiTEBWLtNDqYytK/KrUqfxVQ2ZQqRJ1PuVmoY@i0@tlVZrqtq7W1dqqrqc6kK5bQ8i5gVb9KkbYFZqqkbqVx5CnZ6PlPuQcaaL6blUWU4GVnlPnyKzg@@IMksAzmBagDmzdvY@1/@prKtZivcrkyg3vZBq2hojcq07OBGI8ASlXQFHOK1TCqRLUB1n80noEI2oP7PJdKJTELNoy3UxtA6BEsd9IBYPyYzJidS05SmJ3RLT0Dpf2m3XzIlcRYDhYRIBh9jdx@PLQYbyCTkSvqEt8mUuLHVZ5ALLjO3VWJTkBRlTBjQvMeGdqKHoI4ss08hFEVl6a1YfzOGfjZPJsP9Wr1U2p8OvwZOMfX1Ti6eT8XfKEo5tqFUPOu1VC1LVZQqlOrhBvCs6Bdi3mRQgzweb@p5o1SrNTGF@VQinUpD8uzG2@62XJXridRGToccumKkxzAuMLguM9dG5nYNVKvxDHCmF42ypNEUCIpRjxnFVStZFAkn3wmA0lAIO6Qwi53K/pK8WDSaN6JRJVrGHuQNWXT8gYTjx4mDqI3e0Xdk0J/kklw00MNcUNKqq1RYhbqSsK3NMkUpcildXV5tQ7szSXPhQE9kG2RStepdKVJiDPS4U7GvR3KDsY@dYhffrr7g71OchQtwJdooDNRFmvhi2dhYYp/jCtMdFgXEzNGgZhjpes3IQ/0GMtP3ahh6GfvHIzjdV6sC5b1LwG87XsXFGZ@x2cyMqz5l7zDWjW9KlOjIdbLvVna7R7tl/2sPe@hOJVmWy1E5chmNRK/gJ0Xu0ooQg68IYZHQmhA@i7RlAX3eRUhisL1Lv3@mhMdVxMwSlw@1uvLuid2/LKRV3vAHgXV1FdlMUo6IifXlz14aWcgjx/Vn2kMDCFVxqLqyWexfjCRfDr1vGIX044ND5/7ogcX4RPtCpiFXIyylqzhvvVwStlk@0VYuFgzZOEtE2N1IOcLO1Kheosn4bHhcfJF/UXjx@Nnhs8MHUuR04@2Gi33PzCcLe@d89WvgMZrORBk7rUSmlUxZzHWqVlV928Atc/IMz4Tv6Dk19bbK2bdKDjkDXN7/8g8z0@0CfBugvZYgC7Nxo1rVtwymRIbvv/x93Crhcv/z3Ucs6pkz9nd/8mMj/3d/8q9oBlH0quxRP2c@Aj7RqOfykcvL4eXlFVzcLRupRzhSmbwCZt6prkfm8/1LSdPcysczxl2nnBR@9byuRDw1IoYO8tmI91Y4GakCOPl9@2Ql5zALIvtHdtbQ724jU@jBMiE2H0K2vCJwReHxy7eMwUer2u52bYNMySQrvVPZ9jt1m73DvvF36gZ7WanieK6Oi4v8zuCtarWKUFi0Gk9uRZmRBbfaVbkeZ9SfDK3BF9aWs3W6yNGnG6xYdMDe8rbE6MPplgdNvi2HftaW58Gn/2VtvfKYjOMjyWS7TXvIbFssW4X830oCOqfK@1/@TcPI/d2f/NrbxtvGFwa03IrFnG5Efq7//OfgYc2qdr/ZRX3luPwcDUFzja04v1hrQUsRD7XuMO7fb7xhcw11BrvrQIMdv6Rz1HMoaxp8q6R2jLxt4aLXBGnNtJGJUpakQLskrXjUbSUIBtvCveWhbEqX0lfQCSpTVgFxKX1lDgosBlB9uq2G15@MhjSJPkbh9HqC3YEgEMNXcBuqDVqsK2SuCmIquXUzKEfZI6qRTsQGlufhplZQi0hfgSBiHzA8MtfEdeXo03ZAyGvohfAkh3YN4q5D3H0eoEG2MUo995BgHDseyAHNWfoKKANEBRt0BGZvg4cyCJavAAEgDTEB2K6zbZZW2KUdj5fnO2Zd4Xxk3AvN9Ne0ShgMobVxDbUfuIz@wAo0djx5BvlC5DCoZyFLHwiHwcdLK6DzY3D6QqWLFp1/MCiARRu8xChp7M6dOVaVit1WGKUI4Z/ZQ@yWonxwluMKwPz20iftkpxguBdZ2bcN2A4oHid0getUvglZORSUyfh5JUnw/2CmRY68llXkUMYEiPzipaIFJIPASHaehy22XWG6kVdYgHwLcG8RUrT9VdAIPJ1@ohlf@I5XgOHPI/6@ziB9TsJdfYJvry9qZlDtTXBTXdzahgsDsRiZb16DUuxg7IcOQkFS7D757tgjaKDQeK2/E1YsrSsYbL5zGOFBM4yNDMOpvlkFXxQKfTN4m7jnk4hng/ataLmQod7QdWiTKNrQAmdRA0eAjBJ77XC0J84FbsIu8oYChzHyaJ8d5HzEmDa9otPrKCwOgDZH0Ir1aZNgVldjrUGbGUUWI0ajPYGcAJxCgQjhJmi7SONm3xoASseWxXCfJK@UTHZBK5o0aWOkxzbwVe@BDVWJ4yXFQYHJC/vMTp7gJrKq2wEVWiwzj6AihcWPj7WKTYj6rnvG@vaZxXtwYwuL9D0G@j4orQmg7PwGwpaws9hIJ1gKnBPcF9x5eOW5sZAIhd2IzZSb77S@EWtgjr6lOske4SGA56YToi9dbyXRxPVmnr/NB21WAd9aIHItscC/EsW1xcHOFZLYsKRCe2Vo2Is/jEGD09/oA42gi1vnDBurEtYxIDRb/pJ5LMWQ2q9QBUBlD0oW7vk1HpVwowfAZNSOtaDoCQHvsE9Y2pDQI9@FReyYAjAw6yuL0MENgmI6vHEbMkbjy7NArkDpHLTBDZcYC/bD8D53o5n2Y5uzN9sQ4LDSobgqjBcL/yMb@sDSgfxMSd8AxxxguASTjZgcB7BxWZE56CD89eCc2yWSJSV2E1KCIQRBaoBCqoJ/SigL7ZYugcM90@NbaordwS4uLjTapm4ysjXLwx3EPTz6NDns2qATu8mxNRiKs5psPKNPwJ2bVH5wAB6IuzOlo2iLd2b8LUkdryJmRsSiHS@KleM5bpDdHdD2NrivjEcM9cCmzfVbMTGZg/OfUU9c@vxXQv5TC9ErBMIYgpkmZolWAoAlmq2zROeiXRYO51QgATjkouVb4taQI/9j4Pkme9gJfLhjWrPgfzf7ZzSKCZBk3nU6j5qn0Pc58z/F99CeQiDHumC7o5E5i5G7gr6RgWMzUnvYDKp9cgEjVDPsku9TaE9rs/pC8GkQHCo1v8nDRrh3jXS5HijftBLdp9x9Cu5T7j6dR@pHW5vWuUqGVleYHOR63PLM94lgZr6fK77B49yFIINizXQOAn3OFuyu4G5VKLRPb/4F@VjxGQN4YggEt2LJ2ovT2mnd8ayLrXo82QVml4kQkOMAulYnml60AzNSv3/eH7regpWDO91BrSTwRqtWT3AD5xVMY5BBxBicXjZuTtYdiOF2rhCIBAME1MPAEVWD3XHMVsrBLqnkCIxTk@c05ojVBDJ10r6Ek7ADdYmTnhM2DKgeAoT2QZIATXBhfsnh50X40uH5CI/F9v2qtMX9ADfJidajQMlrRYXLmjJlUggrVfXRBLKjulq5nhTfHbKids0plMwrkf9h9Dc@Gv0OlIvl2BPD8gqjLIWLCk4VAxVCFBeiKqtWQvkKGCS3zL41gpprn@unoraGaLaSfjODx4NJ8C7wEMxYKPNbCs8fWkUmO3IpYIVZpQJJnFV4seTlwicpJ3gQzBPBZj4jiPBcgACM1NJglgg2DQebVipccLDpimAXISSnhOSUB@G@pyuQrItg0HoKTk/G7KmDdooT02SAp/NqFNSgoczwJEwcrH6FG3jhKKWIcy5ziAsED6GKjXzWqi@NvRZCOiS0rgFARrwBoM2PnipJ1wWergZfgYzipPRlFP8SbMBlBTAYieAy3@QyFjAZtYFB4ZfjVA9A2ZXjNUnWqV8Xfyl@ywnf0r/1m5apRZ/6omUqce33D2JZR8qGCmhI@9BTGRTI2JJ5Js4MX9A5InhKY88Fra554bLYEmUb7JP@cePJZt9tJgcmThDBA2mCQ8gVv/2AYyLs7tAdm2M3kynxRpNNbLcsft5msLuOC02T8Oa2oOu1XctzomPI1JbbdWzPSuCx51xlt2i6At96XArrycLoepIk@iB5MxZBc75CVbfRwCPyGo0YTjVTSsGcVpp5huwZjUrY/gVTKDyIJwH0cBhzm6@s1li5HSbuwyyCndits9jhUDhGIZJdBjKsBfo/uPZAg2GeO2850o6wqEo3xzHa4L7nDtwuaH0TT5Mw9DXwB3PYiJA5HBIuCWZik7YU2o2bSkmslTAVEfSzjw7KPjNiphKENxYBLBAjwUbXaYyUHS2JrrEyOh7Mj@/44/E9DuN7vB5faoVfx5k3zSvc8eOiTsfmEMDjHI307Whg0kFutW@gs4BKYI16FQ/wwSi2aQJWGzHdBa@7wrvWAf5IBF8efAWIf76K/usz0A@@/6HZZ@K5occzkDcDnBcYo6MHPH9wMwbeDxRFiiyJLmDt@x8YF/jFU18eoAoBaiwJLgc3s4SCOYRmtxdsse4DvoXncR7VDb6nyVUV7rgEp9F5gp0Zq7PofqNt9c2Z1Y4Jn4kQXD/FR9BgI3n1YQlHQUdCz@VtvRjUXUrgCtU4Ep17Kq1gGTNxriir2Yp7sQPuoZ5ywvBgNf3Q/YZoxi6@Cu@thnZANIobqznnNnZ/DmfDGd8vuc9PjBBylNc/PCdxrfztBAE6iO1iEvNolXXi8ygWJOkDaoTAr7aYZNzO1IeIO4XezMOPI9HtKYXMDQWq@LksLe79vzzH7XU5HuIKnyf5uNGHseRtTPfBPBdiNQ5sLsL2Pq4KuQEZ52O0WrEwRG6zNsdc54ZMQDvqp3NW1CqNJQI1CEmSbmxTc5v0C0XClvEBvLHD6XN4I8CuNW5whvLThn1a4igXRi4DcxjSWoQNKOkAJURFTnKBRsiX5JvB@@VVEGdrZZytG3G2FuIMSsBilCFPUmshSpELmD3rsqBvdcYrpDM6YdsZXuvENlyOa46wt@IyakdLdoJFz6MlEMhRK1raj4FQjrajpftk8KKlYzKcRUufgWFetqJvoyW/WKCHEXyS4S7aCxGO361oaS@mXElj88zy/Hi1aCnIU/Czwz@JIkAKTDdojTjE5rgimeORBRUbKZUJhhzjJbD5RP0wCbpT8OenedCpAOiIfZxb5JnFmb5QaYRqDB4PVBv@rtNLSnJJ1Ob7hw9oPlPgBaOJQxsvHIbAgxoeiS4KI44YutKIBrwBQZSbpeUYsVBN9oHoiNiBQymTF@Mn6mmkD7Rj5F4Dz/V5JHSEiwjv59ciCJ6BH4YnBl6F5w10/OgIIxyTVZaghUR9GV2TKMzrRVxE7odziPq6Fz3hwbu@F55LBDYk00GHo8E5jGzoDheZhFxxarwdDkOdcrxQIvdeC0ZSQZTMFc5kLVKGgiFc@JV1yQmFQ9QWRBA61lJ1XsqCeoFkMTrNZV1IU@WFD1AIyRwo4VbrjI7HuS@M5I@LmwTVFauqIT8sj5Ik16KYhMAabvozMcc89qDxuo9bAX1c89UPOcW@lhgCCIUMYuHy1f0I/d3l@ruvUPtEuBbBMsV6eVV6U71eW8tew7w/j/ZmBqJjgt1XlipHQQxzkkPrIKSZr@O1Gyo@TvngSj6PNIB@Tdv3yRa0CW6h2/W2BYeFWsLofNHyzADLM2M1oW5qJP1zzVdaNIxJwOEJDzCdJ209rjzhy7IYXah/2@x/dAaPFjM4nHkIjxIwukZyXspHE4dmuczLNohtboMiVS8xLshpuDTI5rkliHsaug2GbcHisHF0//DJo69DpZvP5xVRR8/m@GGpxb7WoB7nkGlydFAfLGm2GAk88QIHu7E7ng653jh15BuyhAtrUAZMiMVnP1HGFSHLQvL8WtmFcNxviKIC1tm8GJgLUglVHROrbFvQdQwEscaxLVMA8dVboHeCWmsKne3QaODBxo0GVV@NBk5eajRELYZZ44@IKz@PbCQn3ogOVuQHk1xIEq3WZ/cP2fOHuyfs5OE@e/Bs7zP29cNn7PnukxNcdf302b1HB3sM7v0nx/tMWpgeiYc4YYMS6Hrfall42B7umJZhBHnPHc643IntKdz@2Bywh27LwmGqbc8c3O3xD82xxlUeah@aozPsw7TpoK6BPcb5FnTKFDRjUblp09I7nMvPwG8T2rQDbPMO3LbdscGvhG3foW15/gow1rchB0He@stgE1xJwgOlaOoQHf2GM7AuILgJ/nHsBsCYfP4VnR1tezyA1daYIFxwfTQFT/aPHh8zXNe/d/jk/sHJweGTY/bg8Ag@n3794MmnQM@D45Ojg3vP0Ik8Pj68f/DgYG@XLDgCKY3hyvpXE2@8FgUNvRNVWmc48k1HhAdfi73eqMGzC5MWIXosOnFQ@thm335jtaNlaeKh@oILH2mogMU2d48@/RzqfGa9xhFOfyiY5h/Izzw62GwzxbYpNigsVShvZVFcodpTdYXGIwYzhuccWGVaRB8jc4L5wGkST9u2mLyHc1Sw75uvtaey7IOGiDYANoLyJ6xUGJ1PEo0mtglkFWJr9V3cLZHHxicRig8MetefalKWiGJirgwCxfUKBw72B@nlwAL4HiwMEe14xD2wdGDBPbAMt0BV9ADnjrCs8DEZH05QPLMct3g1GD6gYWGWDyzumdSKLQiceL5RlposON8Jdx7o0yk0vJeHTsczvZZtUxCP/OMJLf0@LxgWPxsMZCIfSqS5beBTBmHTwaEGMe2Nn6KJrsANOE/I7Iw9FqsoGjvByUGWY/Pzf7p90@FToOZTd4j3WAH3lqmIabZ2cG4OrQAZusSAeGbXIh5BuPtCK7Q@NByEvHcjRlPMkaSz6/wpaLchcO8GAr8IGACkLrR0WlRT0VpTBON2BCvHPBc4Evtt34X9Azu3Jy1rIYCYtRV7Zb95owgiJxbaSf48RcIOsuiNNQK1koYyO@4IyjiJVTppBKVgq@cOxzbPw9hiCmjEiao58I0VG8T2slJdiA3pcD1Gx3VCkTaBi1fE2gSm/JBYieP52HkgvubHTgLnQyXM590hOmYTj8iej50lcBDpwsLuF1CEaawcOz9nY8KE65/SXHa8Y3hyXaFSvX/vVH33MoHH13GxwE@M9Ccd4g2MiXFB8aBxPpqwOEK9S5Q0/9ghb9LE0GIOnpCWWMp9YNAO7NnQrrvbKAdufLrxTXtcI3Pdnizfvq3wUCpKJnGIqNeLzaVbgtX8KBMUps7EFJCQ7ARkQdbHfJsEwQzk9V1cF4O5UAaKOChHsN1@7VAfIUL81DUnHZAs4mxFkd0BfIVVaUbF/KhZXNkSzo/ki9i9SryqJOcTSliInDFfRCd8yLqihKalUH11A9z99eBAfn84uMJa7Hj18FHQ7q@F9lG4qfHVsHi1FIL14WDfrQHLK7dfCCykPbEaMK8kb0ILOD1gzsRmJJhNuz7GlzfyjsoegMG6F3tQAqCh2CYODVH7exPHeAAlDGauEB2f3N8/OmIyb59AWJB72GRoCzGIsDfY0/lsW9shYacFSlPQWA6UJ99mYUabf60rzEuJt0JUCB0kIegRCIv5ocode8qlnqhZSIWg2fckEH3KLWJ36csgryYAX0EbEJCdZ1oogdLSZEZ45WN74Unggm4JrhuH5/DTDGted@OJhaNZGFB4TpDZxZUly/PvOdePS348XMHCPW8wwW3QpKG@gXbCMUQ8BI@atpiDa7LFz1KcZM8V7IhPO5z4lVrUsP/@DEWMxJVwrguHxLpQjgVqXD/e9NUcmpCI1YCJMz2FI5/RDA6@iCeb7f@nuGfbahvZ8hl9RSGTYIEs2yQQgjGJAZO4h0sOhqRZhriFLRufNrbbMmB3YNaZeZgfmHmfT5hfOf9wnuYrzuxLVakkG0ivzFqdtYIlVdWuXbt23fatzA51okUvHV@CYJOJd9i9N7kCil88FPSt6ulonSzqDbk51hYIm5rC8gKlsxJ24fFML9AWei05PSSrgtn2yaoy/z9V8SoRq0nRfGZjVCJAXltdffUc7GQrVPHMj8LmNSQ5f46uB3C@j0CGk5DE@8C5lUNXpUcM8ATp2LReDZhEQdjqzFhTYm2nxcjED3BhuRAggzHB8VrAZK2OGCdwmw2dVyQTOmWZaoMxhHVDedRMUf/h6epwQn62vvk/Xh8PNsyEpoMPaJV/0B@GQeSVZ0RRMT6h/2r8WzAc9igb@zNdI5Q0uTE96WxH3nZs8MqtwkTSt5ktaUnvJDa7dZWsgSoh8aKHN4GidK@QFO9l8gWzqXuV/bJYolh9rZgs0h7ajjH3zHd6TyFAczDJJXD5IB@@F@EG/AccXAUSyETefGmijfMsbkQR2DXX6J4WaRYq59Z8svdbYcPvYUgP134RCtt9CQVJCls@2nNmSdZzhVh5QC4c9NJQyrUznk1F4RsKdBFSHAT3Jn43Fiz01FCWkk/c3@5n8@u5tbcWta7njtzr2tsLd6lRtAUsvn7vOrwZ3jV/bfevbluiKwZ/vRw3Jr//JsTqa/EK6lp5yXFa82vFLAW5fAN/18XbHHGuRPAdxZw9t4Xw@M44IRZFdA4vzAu@L40OzRvoIZHgUrF0rbgQXexGxeva2kWxV8wVrmu9iwI6@Y2Wi6Pl/HIaP7yEVRTmGNbM10YXuKaaUtegdyvwKlG68k26hghyDYEvB/6w098vHX6ISeNwA4AiMGnrTQJ1vgV0Dq3Z0PfE6wV3aSkmcwVyrIUbJGuOvILy6NNO8mQUxzQ7gBn0igu72XBMfyeONZfzbgajPqWo2HzIWuK@c2/NKTemHEkUIEutoyL40eXn4TjKk0bFEH@dsBV1Js/btTz6TjoGiBqWpOnQPrdt9ClERKUvV@3CCr3Ab1whEnjt7T0VE5ubdAkusFrokRQPTTn8ITlM5C7wERUg8DMgbQNWQTv3kNw@LGg@vufxgb@QjGpEfjJkIG/RThFT0PxbfCP/Jiq/CQRgws/xnsuTIk6584KNJPsOknABA5LFD/6oZkC3Su6UOWwswub6ihFwshQnGmG1kkzwfe4Oycm0gn@yBZk8vU01Q@d3ODuRhPTU8i1EWlKXUtIW/nSjYmmjWEYVU5kNUsw9Sw2UdMHx6CCAYTURO0G3C0gzLeYicuAj@ffK@pd1/WEN67zQyHN6Zio9E0v3OJ2RinJ5sMBHmTbMTHbqW5TvQdhRNneqrqKgzYsHPd3wYEsS5S08lTf0Rv16J8q8pbuSuVInbMYSMkbK1xm9zynzsTKawXV6jdMlf6/IntdYxvK@j9ePv5bsoICMZ6WtSYJLvV6n@44XLZ2CbGYDNYXg4tjfxHY8KKUPppxOYAeHcn4atlvFCMpyXs04NGbsrc33tic3Ge/SSTTYi3FqYM0YIwaVqM5lItyYHBahHkqeN0AQTGQ0oUbulio8kYUnBljMNa@qZS/IqQEOTUsO8SL6Rd7jHzXY48ipfKnZiXOM@Zgbz97NcQLRpDtvzyZTfDZBdxH@KBv1xCoS1T1JQpw9SRwaUmBdZ8A@2C0Ug8/recKcKNRMMUV3nSIpHWXIK/Z9rAsx8cH6Z3bJ@uDDHnvQDcaihMcMn7ywrJiD@ygIRyHGdqJYNOHNYNBFrSNt@O7IhVoGCllZRXVLBNFY2T2rgpY9nN/FJ@mQDoU8cYSQ79BAJEoIb9ptdCZDD9j@HU6tKHHpjDyr1JuwQAPGzKsVdjMPxE3IWlM47bdNJLjnePQgpcOB3wg8C/ZoIex@LG5qi8e3lKej3whGD4MlbcOy/nLTafy68wH1uW/yuVd5g2S3Uh2c8169jhysgEgqYSUH29jV/GvLMnTDDdYNZxCgK/Zxof8MvBncBr1eYJVgxaCMIWxaw2B4GzQ9yzoOtBIY4SIro2YS/bD7N8MGC3dg0@UDM6KXcOiyOgw4DH9xfWZ1cYN0Za6FSqtI2wxdfdtpIgGVx0mrj9phUlhgmACmBxa6DkZAlCVHxFEi3bPEhfYu1yiIAmpgnBNDN6HJ0OuPOg3oGZJkWV0AxWqQqLJeM4EJ1Nfo@ugc7M1CAN1jIgooBJQq6SkcLKk0/0M4CNkwpWP3Vc9kYfbr01iB4R4MOzD7RgSmXqFiBu7QwScfK1VRPdo7@VI6Lgt4/nR89LmyW94V22ek40ZFOUW2FR@P9mF20dp01pofwQe7VIWSNiVYpcMzUf7503G5WhVHx6Jy8Gm/AtAA/HHp8KRSrrqicrizf7pL2neAIA6PTsR@5aByAtlOjlyqVRWzonLiaE8clI93PsJrabuyXzk5oxr3KieHWBlq9UviU@n4pLJzul86Fp9Ojz8dVcsCG2btVqo7@6XKQXnXg/qhTlH@XD48EdWPpf39REOPvhyWjwUZCRit3C4DlqVtOMJiTdTO3cpxeecEGxQ97QDxAMF9V1Q/lXcq@FD@uQzNKR2fuRJotfyXU8gEiWK3dFD6AI2z0s9QBfpl5/S4jPGPkBLV0@3qSeXk9KQsPhwd7RKtq@Xjz5WdcrUgrP2jKhHstFp2Bd4lR1UDDKAWpMPz9mm1QnSrHJ7AmnH6Ce0dHOjkL0AYwLIERXeJwGgGga0FIh0dnyFUpAN1gCu@fCzD92OkKVGrhFRAi4qdEzMbVAhEPDGbKQ7LH/YrH8qHO2VMPkIwXyrVsgMdVqlihgoaZJwB60Clp9Rq7CfAix@BWS3FuS51p6jsidLu5wpiLnMDB1QrkluIbDsfJc09jIZrCFE6fZQZ@NemYKU1/ek2wOCS0xKZ2TIaHTFp52i3DCuyDFZlRwmnsOqsJ0IpmWmw0uhEeI2FrGkGlzfteqfX6qOPqS7Ggo/rsO3ipSwO3k1xbj1x94WUr1CBVKpe/1yqw0G3Wq877veUjKHxXAkpBn8qlyPbiOH18eSNgp@NDab7ZoxQWy@lopMM9VABgTmZ@i/Z9M2/DhyRzTYDWQyd9xGwEh2FrDa5QlUKTI3k7IgXaERVkmSC3juSHahgWoH3GnWUk6JlJGXqh/Cndx@98OJgfIDZmcVd2SweYgmNzu@BqoYroZAI9EdGJOi0qEovDIJf2@mcWR2e@b12v99MO44qQ3lHcA5sp51nil8G7UTxTLI8IUtqZxlJP1TnbtrCaP2zJJmQ/eINqWVp/FMf0Y@jsOGYDyg1papIWC2FlumXXBwtklwhQ1ugewV1Mu75Dko/V77gaS638rqQ@P5Rf@exhfaCGIQWFrwalbugn48XnAEGGMXiAJJ0ZISMbNYoo@xNdOY7yHiFme46TbT8gbX6KqB1HUgCG9kbv2vWiavxsDM2sYd5@MNx6WD7dG8Ppk7E9vX66pu1gqXDbv3s8u8Z1kORYinq2ADWcdinUZIxSnZg40MjxYilHbE/MXA2ixkxyrrqNPqIcR603UbckgknMmxuiLfJ9NBEzw6QDragABzzluLXmSNTMkA61lQHW3Ptj2mL78NeiXhAGrN0J9RrY/yDsPXwV0NcN0gykGQxip0LnAunC5r37D1lKkqHGwrcg1k8W/Exh3HTNCBRF9nPonctvUneNnoxZFNGHK/U7VQSkJhPYiGUXUWPR/YnijMiBcAUPQy@/Cz5DR7PZIA7Cnfnh6PSqApk3NMlUU4dCaNlo2sS8sVWEbro5Utd06ZAKb8jkaKxJ8XJOjCIMRoIFbwqBG1844ALOo5IskqygH2/6IhvzKkYvAPhFCTHynfg3FnNkVAKKn6IfFdRKQTD0kFOmGp3ug5LZTnTcSwUOWNk@iF6EPw/kSYz4G/CiROgR9QyggB@FyUJKtMKjq9ElM6dUjQY2o2ImuanswjMg9kxV7phUnszZv8aIIHsnYn6cEZhD1vpGQRAJkfBhjl@tUnalQ9Hp/e2I4ujnqTXuB6khVwr1FIxBTezduHStstVuhV8cYTDsiajwn0oKt7zwe2SRj0cmRJHefEitBmco@J/ZJdIAKIHPHHpFVutJjkrJ0eZmgdkqCVjwWnqiEmwLX14VGu3JIwQmbG5X2q@FKEA9BbiM91Ouv6jL9g8Nx5xkVZicUJR8DAeOB6TcfGRIesuyRCzGyCcF00ShuANIaM7XCC6DJ1C9UXQRPoFGYpgJZHVYRRnEKdbxwPS0rJ6p7EnySRyqMb@tMeB6AOWaqkcHgf4kBia7vKeOPAngHL3@5rNLJZdqvZdtF3EylgsIcvjbSiNfn8IW0cf2w04up2J44kvUugQ9MKboYxfCOtZZyglEmrTD9XgtolP77TMcAx4Qi3sjNBboekRf1CTrgO0EOXwJOPMmkgD8yoe3VJCx854OS/Sm1HKJtCEwpISETfFmri/51xMUBkyNCAKdkJ9uCCbTaoH9Q56@N31h7/i2o9boF4zaOrIpAZIkgVyJ1V6FOOxMeKmD/ohSTSgK1ACoimRZ0GaNlSFNfqNZCdp12RH0TExdim15I/Xo5lUWUtBRRHjytqB@dYy0JlIpRUZGlQHC82vrBIqsw5cD48exihaaFxtLezznp5SNngTUXyhto74xPOmfjrDJynkL74IcfTAF9Rxyy0oIox7VtSrTs9zhB/aFHzpBMOmKROFnUzTH6D4jY4@/R7xohIdyrB/DX8UBhM4ATSynXGWYNTTP/WvevWdftdvd/odH85pGMZ9zDMePk7oETusPezfhXTRDyU0jUzNSfTM8WU4DBu@a71kwQjNFY6CQdo0UxgNJ6UrDhNBknM0AoxuhST@HiRjpOkyr1ejQlbc/5Ts8fJO4dGyr/KzCrNGHwHICW4rYUHBPqQjckwynE8LUxkun8pg4HgpMsJ3HrHYi2H8FkhEapgYxgqZKbMEsxF4MnsU41pz7DYpBuEQAy0FuwFeOROm6bPr4/27MIu8Q0uBDZFfzxlFWYsyxjiE@DB5nNwrb/5k7AGBH0A//2oWt8xiBJriWiraUsjnFRllFHAh88AOzdE0E8Ms1mnDKtSNAa2Pk1DjyZPHqEGWP7ApkmH2prgSR2QaDj54d1y6DlNOfeLgorIoFh2K24FbkNIonXucYYPn7Gdp8KMSlyVnODHtSMhpA@nHSNUAKuFVownzWhNljqn8/IhZWfneXksQsDjL5My4Ujdtq50LeaB0eH1FtVZ/CJOxnaCeNPVYDEf9weJ3Uu/RuWNmZLZZtG44zrOGwMxsRVgsl5pE2uIEHycFK4lPgmniFCNLM@AhPL7Ss2bzJBHHxTqOt2J98gwdHqNZZDelFxXd300e@7go3qJFr1po9JAi3DFIaUF/r9Wh4fXHZxAJk49XdZox6jhl1Cf8aIBKkElT6fspRNwncU/QowmUw3qbQDuzfx4latJIToU8VUmxIJdITwzcjk6bMC8NWmh8gWHieIerJym94Ry7E1Ll5TOXGGQYExgg7oqDTCSHYglu1FkJPqLbAVrpOloL5XEmgqct08JBB/3XBKOo/FK4Iy0e6pNM/qLAkMYaEpwqKNdTkJS/ObzW6mOCMkUKGOIzSKFbNDU3XX1/q360LZAPIHBpSpaWvjkXG@OIZcAG/phJ9THugaOqZMnYiIoPhDpNDTAW4JTS7gZ8XMXdX2fIHI/WDXIYwQGCP6fxZ1mWwHDeazlNbSwybk4wiyPJzaPNEZktLhIxFL8j@eVQ5K0uHVwBQMAYQ/liHiBgWFPCHpUCFHrH5LwYorKPoGAxj8MSPlJU1MjOc0Y6ElVmeL1q5MjNyvHWhJGZCQQ2FrPzRIjAnmV2lggKLHQzcTFyvJndnigHbIgV7zPFoStkr8RpqHuOCQiPhK2eUWp54eYkB1Pi61Unlqj5m1Lf5ozUXDIV6KMxrGXyydT1XCw1Vu3KSrxorCTQwzFrjSUCKRwTYT0r/Ng/ck0xQ55rm1DjkBHbZUj77B4epe7w3Ob9NRSb5JSt9hgKnukZro5fdb5iJRaU/ekA7GKRVAYYu/2HW6ssUxUm8q4AikunnF3SfCCkHauNSz02C0@6KtKeDlCgzrT9lvh8srcXC/t6OVGGRtfBcDWXyyETX5rB75VtNYqSOv1sPHe2ddPtZgd3Pw0/X2Zp7g8CuhJgQ52gA@gSGBSh1x@2@WYIxAGyYu6MdGTFs/5Nq2VewYAaSuw86DbOKaMhCFqAOtro5fMJCYAIpFxgf8EGYvt@EXr03fm80ZRQlBoKSqNJ8K2ttGdAHvzQQvtsrakiYDgxK2smWLec4tY3XEHwZhPqLApf7HyLzJPtj0G323fFF7wqGCMFzD0kC@ztmQVynAU1jOTdexNSPFpXBLedruFXjFlMXkdwamFS90youPAYG/84aJfHg7Rd@2rDsgJNXsZmLmN8alfYbduRweK/AyzzIaD9Xbmv/UG6QXRKZoalXo7g6AkwepV3Z559YlkckolJmj2fG4k6G12PgjVA0x3aC6hY9tS91JJHsmvi2ufjfAtpmGMYEieMufJ9JdDV7M@bFm9Hrdb3zYp0DQB37B@aEfkmlB@bEEkHQCNQDj@gJ0bR/pcMDOu9REAR3uDgZR3T8w4WqGMBy3rRKP52ly6VSmJhsLwsSqVteMhkRGm7JHbxw/a22IX3bXx/WVxZXS3wnLvrfIOP2@rjg9gGGCThXG5cDXfhFdKK6DeG1trYxQvZ4oJbWKgXN7cKYbZW2ka3fnj6x7/9xz/@/T@zJfny3/iyTS@1rzqT53nZhca3hZcPBXyv7V4sLlzWFgYXi@0Cctk/KWp4vzLK@JH5qDe8tFK8ChhfyY5UnbMp@owsKtStftf@8FeYXTZEqhFmU/JryDdH0RybagTG9wD9KC/hCK8uHUge5QGJFACdoDgeeqcRoAEerDdAScAF7UC5POtWlOAew8HoDFqrkpKReGjPehugT0sUSQF9cWHFynR6YdBDCfgt7Xm5eZblw29nVJf8m/16ELa3@2OxdJ4WSzmx5Iol26af/Npb@OosZDvoncvZ4Dhg2y6kRKoFNDMUYYc2enR@oLt2EuS2rAW6sgchqTAVlJm94Fx9@iNnGb5wLWxbc3hppmARCSmZsEjq20LvAbrlG@R4sGOuNrRRqMtTDFVmaFR0/@IWyA/ZECCq@ZoJstGHKlHTRx7J@JRVX2RfW3SbEAFGsh5/2KNxjx9gLVroSZvn2FkKrzki83n@imtjgZ2hCW1M4fojBEihwsfJHHkSLqYWLbbyNlpJzWQvbLN9kvnY1mESjJRtOhf6V2EwAVtzm4Rb6Em/FmnIzeoVYXe0esWoyk7afgvLKHJ90x11BtJdgWrHAfVN1/bAIwl7lAAxHI7ZvzE9wkhQoCJFJbqFL8uaiGYfm84joSdd06GDHY81RwYRsl/TMLbvE2PbyZKXiGIH5gFCSpvytfxON5RRV4ZE7LY/vMTbAf0WXag2Yr0ZyfPwmtQExv2WRtojyGRyHo1naEpqMPTb174rUof9k6E/qcCyBTufUcNzoIUYggmRwMEnq57VPIUwt0h2CVFEN4Ush/Dygu5EXo/GfWtrnxPsUjUUZNgVHAQxdiJKBvexvkrQMeLqP9AJJspTk7fWRsoplmZetDSSkGzTbYaG2dTQsVQN5tjRA8e2GFU9MhUvyEI3uNBek@IXZvIuxgiQddvSC1C6Iqy9xfpxdWoHPT@2OA26lnL0zxYEr4s4nukqSrZGstTNp/noxjvECvaRX@NRIHhtUuGMrLl0eu48lNe5pcx1hIJ8a1v8rC86@gI6usCMPEPEaa/Dk2VihYruwPBEhSz/AUKr67cBv8mdP0FWPE@l381nndrX897FUvq8d3/@u0OYyClZrbIZkZLKbDVjybECK2PWjb0qq7RQhRo878UznPcE@7AYJABEsuna1@zFfRYQOk/hnfLnKSZIrMsQk@zT9WURfHYKzVQci2zKmnOWHNX56Xd5R8DaSr/Yh/zB4V/AQh0qSUwP55xhC0CRn@5vN@xyEmbXV3KvV/Kv4STUDsaZYXCD620mvLkMxrCVCPE4C0vP@e8xbogR4mEc@gX4OIZ28rUm7HsSSiclOYXKYU71WJqtoIzHPAH5gcoULhVdXBydx0flIx74XQEsp/JSLCg2HTS4L43rZ9i/xnr8EOe1pHcIcyRaGbCNCIlQMwhZXb7yGIc6argskp@TJ3YwdisBge7NpozVotfvZeRmzfEWC7iJRq@Z7npuPZcco1NDNDZCF@RmanFe5Lfevfn7fx39lhqltlayX4bwO0r9llpbT/EjPMDbK/V2m9pKbWK2tYfUJAtnYHh88/f/gfJbPwEcTJlswp@tVQVrbZLayhSpyH1qaw0e8isrUO///u1v0IYFPrHhXawLdVcQYgVFkR2/R7wL6aKCreRj6WI0rZBjFsJgC0M4m8MLGkaNV9ZzJKZLSauK20BGvlL2KHKJJ8OsEZkKsSRD2VPAzogLFLGCDINUJhQtYdhuKLMNZN4ITfHLC28thBPAL9KcQ1epTTdehGgytMDHIujANNcI53l@2Mq9s7V5x4atbEoKaguJRzs5166/Kvwf)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/n8g2l)

This answer works in IE 3.01 from Utilu IE Collection, but not in IE 3.00.
I didn't do anything to disable JavaScript – it just didn't work.
This may be different with IE 3.02 because [this IE 3.02 distro](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/internet-explorer-3-02-win95)
from oldversion.com has jscript.dll and Utilu IE 3.01 doesn't.

IE 3.01 treats `:` followed by any number of `:` or letters or digits as `*`, but `*` itself is not supported.
Also, `a{color:111}a{color:222}` is equivalent to `a{color:111}` in IE 3.01, but `a{color:111;color:222}` works as expected (= `a{color:222}`).

IE 3.01 CSS code:

```css
:,a,i{color:fff} /* goes before other rules for a and i */
: u{color:000}
```

Golf: removed `*` from `*+a`/`i`.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Internet Explorer 3.01 displaying polyglot #310]

Answer (score 2):

## 311. HTML+JavaScript (IE5), 14418 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$]aat\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*26qkp16*^[.qx]"[8=,k]Pk PPX~_~)"xvy"\( 7# CO|"14" #:7 9 7 9                      7 222222222222222222222222                           "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[###### mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz 2#z#111#y#y#y#_# coding=utf8             ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退                               @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####; #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 2>2*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"   '\"' ` L       >"082",,,@_ 1   x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*      v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1  >>>>  \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>                    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!??   ?!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v           @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>  
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
XX  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

























































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,5,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:8][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
*{+color:fff}:,a,i{color:fff}
a{-color:000}+a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
+i,: u{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{:after{content:"260"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
#  ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
COMMata#8;&&1Prers>80::gek:epos>Ex Cr u Uitharbody$/ $5"6c"F ._#a*ee gi[os]pR 8ogr ca34* 161  prstdae7#text6,1 ,8 ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4od""n;z cop>s'0}e}eq67+?4[0][ ] 
 ;:在ent
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^e*n*\              \! 99n*n*es*s      \*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "( *)//dd"    <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcxtLdiD4ucvzI5IFXgFFoAqowhsgQFEUdcW@kqgmqavbDUJQASgAJQJVEAogAVFUdPfs9rrH3llPT9vRbs/4tnvGs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuyvE4755B8gPzY2HBvuf9B7zsmsQoEEQKk9jtjY2AKqKisfJ0@ePHny5Ltper2f/zyCF3vq9mfdvjtmY8sbs/bIPrdGGrs3Y3dN28saaUlCX7uj7mRgOWOvJEWYzpg3Nkdj1jed7sTsWiwCtgabf3fs/tgaJZhnWaxp9d0LcE8z5lgX7MBp2W2AxMbumeXYb6wRuGUYu2/13w7ejlnLHQxMp@2x4ch2xuSaZeypCR@dSeuMmU1vPDJbY9t1wCnH2DOnbw6abZOR9@HI4oHyDEC1zijMokuBscfuyLMgBrdleZ6LlkWwNEe2@2j3yafX/Osp9qkJSA371vRa9LrOntvWqH09hME@P3nw4Lptmn2mug57cBMlPcN2J2P3YHwdfpbtdi3HZIZW1Izrjjkg5tjqF1KF1IITuD2wR5Cbpsi10jxnnMmgaY2A@CILL@xxT4MAJy4nOHOd/oxZUwAGOHbAmzVmNuYWy6ZS6BP@x1bLddpz8GBlARyAaw2G4xlTmeMKHgAnd8S8odmy1LbVtwf22Gqzvg3YuR2Bjccgw9mZNbtwR5DxKmdFQsQbWi27Y2MQkQJPQma7bzUnXeZOxsMJoOextu2ZzT54a85Y2@qYk/44wZrgBsQj@4ue5QiUbKeL6Xg@t0EIDhQBjv2mDrSx@30G6JwhOhi1x7bR4QLt0WvTIiytNoLan5MLIJl9z0/9YsQL0WC4pyO3OzIHwKhti2jw@cFT5rXcEXzBjX55KVgHpmWO2fY2i@4/uR9l1YCM2qgpBSStsEvGWMR3ZOdmf2J5bGDOIG5nDIWLuZR/fggJvLPoRrTEouk0M1Isk2EZKGwFZmRTDIpEEQxQao20DneOGQWW0YHvs9EExtMZmV27b3EoXbffQUB55Fgjywx4pjLRBHdtURx5li6wXJ7lsywPzyIrGhAJQswwvZiFOwc3QCgCBjrc6QyPKWALZCdIAttjHXNg92cc@nCI4Fssq7M8QAQ0dYBsFABC0UAIi1cY3rgHhO2Z5wBS7dtnKC6sQGJgbiXhldzaSpLIQtnIo/R6Vr@PsQKhgETZAstDrDlIdAZiBjoaBcNPfLdHySe88im4Acc8pLgA5E0BpVJIqjzc8A1iyAB5Y4BwMUBeGDrYG2BOI1TwlwO3HORVLiCt0SbagnSFsDoSEwWKjjSAYAyyLp1hkHkZyN40Zm82zQBPQCCfYyBTCjorZFghz4BcxRQD0uuADOa9DrJMByR0BAZZqkOe6oCIDsyiA1A9nWVSiK56Gt0hbBrCAgn0DITJgBnyRc/hDeEg43WIUoc4DaM4Zy3AzchCIrNp4jkjB5mXBzcglgG4GsAtBmBrFMAdwxaAcAVkybxPCLM/7JlIC8gBZGRgNSBIFnAi2OAfzEY@zVmKfDetsd2SriQoVbwGDEscX3qgBABpwkyGFSgw4Jx7YoEEVEAgLQqriWf1gYtAhrRMMCPbQmlHyeHDsccaylmopiz3HCtSKv4L0XgkIpojrEVBXrWt0YihX6hsvQQJE2/S9KzXE6xr53h1QDpZIFg7pt0PEKCiY46pHoB31IP4Zotod0bugMrXAIVF33WHK8QuiKYLBPTQvbDmqM8llzkc9kGeg70FhJiYfUDmwiR9gNSFcKwcIQiE4Vo9GwBSVCBX7ZHVItqLpEPoNEjgRRRLzKjeSSOUe6FqIc2GLghVD8M4k36/BNWd1WLparJtnSfRhlcdi1UG4uBXJlAfChBNE@pyqkwRiwDSHUOjaurEz1nPHSwmjYuXgyDpPRurgP6FOYPc64BksabmADQOhtW6AxX3ADiG5yDmhMcrngPWdp3oOIByMYLqFRIdpARA9okmY3tggT7mQhDM8QwhjcKNMGvOgJWJWhmN1DGOyTVCadJ1QnGLTMiCFxao2NqTFlIN47Yd4iCoEDyqraoAlyudGhqgyI0ss829oXaBGIX0I6jtLCC6UAVaBAg1FMvxQNvxNGajWggM33U7wGNURYOqAUHn8bQo7ZjywGqqtTSJKI18MzjrM5u1hkMG9qCfAFoPUgWoY91XNnsDjv2ex/qtyWg0Y9MhZIA9AF/jltvpANO@sYY9AMEGbdaataBUQiqRaaS2SxKoNbyW5OBr0wI/jgXJ3nv6dda1gNpQI3cAU@L0eQKGQ0oCkcJ0eG3tmEApTEJrOCOyAJggRMd1NbRvu5ZHPALaTFDiMTLP6lKJgOLVmcugAWofwJygETjAsiBwRKlC@BihtDQxGJXI/E8tB0pMC5gRyjpkH@qju6wDun@oskblzmy1rOFYsIdLUsx2QgrN4QNUaMhWFcA0rydt3gVdbAEDCbxKPueEanDzjIQrKvqkZ5koYkUDA@p0xwpUWMYFSn92I3rwcX4tdvkl@lnA4KW8AochlQTU7kg2TMYoQVAo2q0eisAxChnSMqCQjSY3kw924ehHA6Z2grgRGx2kjaQlAyvEYzUMFe7@TUDasI@wqgsW6HXB4hbQpjdYAtkNkOy3w7Za0tRAFt4GdOA67hKoQMwALnpZdKG8IGY8Rqlh9gNmpOLiLeQRyul52xfrL6g6h0N3BCWDC50ZSjKeZSHucnk7JRZUEQq0mxdrVKgpoljPj8e8zTXsQzuIihiWVNAnTZAUIMR4CwBknstjDCFMpZ5gCfwuSOJzZoIq1HEsVEnN0YwDgeRBrQwRzZg9GoEYPMe6gVc9fh2iEZ9CVWC22yhZkRxU7q9HriFH702a9vR6M6OFltorTzo3R6yDLYwR6BpQiGLRjhdVymRPIUNOctIdjpMUlD9l8EieNMjyWAcaLVARPABBczxzWjF5oYjJCSZPxp2CrIABA3LVjH3VHI6vY/cK7JBpBmdQrumrzLpQa6sqPFW0I0zQIamhgzkC9QIKIWjZxWK7abK3ID1GTJ3uUWhUC@mta5kgLstpB3EJQiAu4fRqPApv1CKDGqrVMAXonVJOlcQCAT@QEhRQBotkUtSfaEFKHncjdYZbThzqHmAxroEo7DJQ0aECiBEyNugcdsseN4SWcueOr69sVCrAbKBEgdhsK2Hl3u9H0UBSg2eNlBARiTZ2j8dYNmIKpBc9X3FsQFsCTq1U2eW4N4ISR99XEngCskoOcrJPWJHPT@yzSft6RjtoiZ5kLHWgK9mtsVyWoPLnpaGyjqrRBaqC8h9FqiLzYngCfYN5yRYzVBbeRpaHWm9FoBLK4RhiIHh1KYl4UGE3Z@i9WasvVAJugsLOpVET0D8TLfVAECWETuAX2hsllQPB4sDhsKe7Jw8roixyx2TTdkoLFn23ZfbJehO9y37YRwf3jnaPvt5YAqNvN0vXLZJ2ppDDqnYyVbvOJJnRjNJmGMYc8P3GetgYcNGPLAlnprrTkKo0a0HlMvXJeXj02XWSgCaE5KAYwIz3NZWG@wGlS2qaXu9aJcy68ThEGQTx/TL1gPkwAwOiju6mj8/TyZs3mHnXkRoKe8SsPzE5AN8yeeD44TR0vKaA@U7NDq8RKSxoobaD/Z9zU9inj8@nqDVfR4ZU6RDLfHr4YP@oQmB7pndm9fsqeUl6Y9ClzFFbA57vT9qWtMwPiD8wtVhcmyOO@jThupTArdYCged5y1bABwDYxNFcpvYHftK8HuC@dz1tZKu2Ag6gb4JwXa8M60Otj0U0hAdWcS1s6S6rRclhXlkFVktrrMB1sdpqZbNWPlMMV1uteZztMNABKcW26@uNI3A681S00eZapFCrBfrHj24g7pESCU0B1cfM6zON4vL6ErZeVJtFveQetNDcvqU9J4knM1lJJqN@x6fW8qjNGfK/P7XHsZTC37oCfiH23d0D477vWXTUUQcGNRqwCY4106iDAw0tD3jEcftu12VbEIZrh36EoDatTOZu13Vu5JCJlpjUCI5cgPzF/hpzCHWN/YYajhQq3Fzlox6m412AlNZzaSQSUYhAJcm/9so8N4Fc83QfH3xjHyoRPZtKBeYUXUCCUBgiF5paIVuyYCpEpAl8liYwGMW4Udp9BzU0jICJFoIuCLg7d15qSRJTSy71vxSlr7o3KP7KnV1jLbDhrAWGEMkOnjx9dPBk//HuF6djI5td@M6kijkgHMTXBF1I63G6YWnd4kUTk4XgIlA2Rli8QApMoIHid4dPvBEIbg29aByBFVzDx39iX3V7TtRTrifmAl3VV06Ls9BjLHzcqwgIDe12HxsjIz5shvU58k9vPB56pWQSSnlv0tSg0Zp81XL7ZjdJ4aBi6PeTOjZdDg6xX8NbFgKQ8WYWD8H7tEB1mFHHodkfuNB4oaE4FA0sxsFTZ1Xf7vagLYzjddZI0QIOptQk29BCgLZyMkgbCWD6AtqKt59PMmftr@hGgfO1njIySdn3tlD8we9Gx4KmUwxqKyCFcu2Tnd45vcNmIKUR0nUgEaZtiSEbrAv6DBRJ6izFdr5PHJIW2E2KsoJo9HqCnbggpZLZVCav57JJaJZBMw10VhW72tSBOW711LGrAjzV7VC/QYgLO17LdDraljD4yILe9wkkNV17cXrq1EFBP71DuOFAWG1Wr@l1pcxuBtkS/pUycO9C8pB3fQvgXTICa9KbrZBnbfOmOGubVLraLDkeDEWdow7Z411QpN64IK/bVrjsYYBk2DG5teA3iZ7fJZd0CPUxqIQPpFQSChTUtMB6ScRLBaUX1UPgHJBboQBs3pvB08GHn0NyBBvdyPe2G/Worx71Guwk9YZAROpjbqGU9rB/cAy1Y8D5KKUhc1FIswsrit3npsc7KSGQGHT0w0NbLYBAnfFBR7QTDLYCE1Aoap6D5AC@wt7S3ryXERv9wGkQIeGEnQ@gQTg0aNAFOQOBeUJ2eUJ4TGSzmKQzx71wEFrTYgW1aY95H787GeFgnt0Opw28pw3uB6BR4kJynUb9mlaL97LywJQKaASabGANXOxKAO2KRIFFSTD5iCG2BT3sqIZilVJx4ATgq@zuHkixlsX7i9QBNqKApfZZdDxK7qrfSJrqG@DmNboVJn43PIBNmX7iE4B6IoMRbOolET2gpJ24A/L0nPpb0PGer@5Kw9m4BykGDpPNiju0nOttPt4ijCllGmeNRkHg207sMrqxsREtRavRBJh2wLSNph00xcG0QyaVTOhPQxOFSJAJXWsUAu3q0auaD3mq1JEHpqg5vLGHMbNWKqXrCbOmi7eBbwWyAigPvlV8AZyoUqmgUVHk6gUO1YD@Hkr7HvLOcWtkDwUJvgoKAf8WNEgTEaB5j9r8yCpj23Q9RQaVETQaLVQxY6PoaS11Wj@9PG3HT6@iCQytlM0KtA9BeI1jA607cidDUNxqmZIKsk2ppUv1crMSTUW3YrGC2oeITEX5pKDETU7rWNQCnoqdnkaBpII6tVZvRPCmCUNRAkIBHh0bWhn9fiyqXRYg/qZSV@JRCKtEEyCWK9Eo0KWFRPAo0dgjwJnogT0FUkLBhCouPKZAApLGpLC4fsMa9majsIeg1w20bOxBnw/GQ2EgKR6Wkm94@LBCt9DS9/Ve7g@UW@y8Q31pOOPSXeKYniYXJob49e652hm4YzP5uQaNJi1UXUY3oklVhZqQXDgkSvZj28MibDqWO/HCPY1LO0AxdrA96U1AWPqzZhLAVfZQslo9l0U37wJ0FgzzYFWCI1YqH/fyAbRbGtwoRFErwcES0C5oOokNchGnmvBeGZ2Q4KLH75vP5oavtSC2MoVhKYzI7jruyFKBJBBCoskfNFVIqjIxo@SAer5ujEsIV6rSsOFtWyARH/Rdk2jLxXVoPGg4CIWH9jkEObLaUh/kRwfEo8bzYmS1k1sSDc66ox7UEJAalMRGkFsD4ZB0vWFbG08hqBTDCjfsyFt3oHResLZhGLlWtlPy3ZArgNg9yCRslTrQxPWdVB0cFZHJ@7xbyG@jPzm8v8/7TqiyxeoV@9EaA7c9Ab1StJuOLKebYPvAT7bjDmwggx/@zVn/yHXHvJUPH6t6Znij2R5M@ib1@VzvllkbruU23T51Ba0LOvc/GXlm3@SdUL7r7uePQdd/dnJc0UohT0nzfLA2buyHXB4tp@dBeMyRhln94SGPM6a8mZWx3vIno6GYEQ45dJiIqWiQR759Hu39IoVjKMK@gPYDnIYGurLoRaDPwFJ4LJJHnJqGM3qE5aWeukL7lW2wwJ9O/rjiOMf2UjfI/nzc6SxYp8n6TEXR1J9bZ8iaT1FbaCOGUcpyTzhfbcFPGFCO/ATT1q77E8IrmGLQs/r@COIRKCY4SgZ1ex/VJ2iboCbO545ZoEgPcTCEJDQOsbEW6JrejW4LKFNDlfuWIhtUTqAOS6LmIm0mmejiLlNJcVwxNOlx6elC0556T7arfMAam04j3mpL8s73zQaA2K6W/dlEq7xhTNFo4I2gEm4QgpJJw/Y3khpMwvCoT12iIGXJS0KrYWqk1NNpfr@e9IgIHSafnk4/SRlfQOMD53xt3kl2rTJGt5Ja9M37oVs9EBssPl0kGeTDxOm4/bbKB70g/xlvLmFGiKkGwawzEvhgY4/8CWc2TmIREwNBXIbmqt2Aey3rqjc9hGa3BYCgNFyyt2eJ87esBjXYueYN@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@ZZlPBBaUIHeqaKAlhSkji5jCLpGYREoDqcjevkULmW0ajNhAxhnDnL5XfpsW5OMjF5B9JGZAh3UOEhpiegqKjlNJ9htvi@O/6MIbBsnzazqvei6Hw3Gd03bOXBpFCkyNlKZnUc8MQg/O@jdDdmyvR48FrwEO3K@xCjtv0OzQY4kHGkwRw/RkQd30QsOG7DSTR/SiHvslMS9OTVmItml1Jk6XxjTRzNTXt/hUiwXy3Gk27VVegQg428x/L/EGshJLnqFlNN0vPdjBA9UiyE/eJpon/fqsJrZAd6ikxhBKvP/LN9tA/5u504P6CvszA0MDNAXMKbWzMrNEUPygx/KM5d3uk75tEmHIdBvIljmCJJn9wLAcNA3tqyroGwMcqBA5DryJD9BF17AZx5yPM/rv5ZEsG6pzQG63Vvm9NsuLR0WDStBcbBMRuM5lWxSIhCzPBGvKB3ZCDXcUuLcj5U/FYsTMPN97k/GEP0EdvjUT7SHe68qm8JnKmk3dggap2bStNVk@Ms8mbVcdnnUDtTi3xO889TSyrIJWIgaZG2hcnnyewJHdheref6/yNq9fkxf0uo0rPGfiDdUmte3b/IsKwmBNDKM@f67yYouVSoFhNdXsPj0@kBMFdGAUMcciiTNY1RDR7Gtk7pvNGapCvY/nsmC@AkicSiseT6VXDFgPh6vDY/uUwheLy0NPtRanx7KehySfJavyvjlKsJg3e0uuQnVlD8y@arRDxpXCfNl0hxteg5FSCmOd4zjR@dKcm1MfK6TWpG@O5qY1LD7Hwx@cWNXPLaoNUZZbbt/2sED3V0lNf87dPC6cp0yP0LwKexkl29AQxXpcDUzLpYDbGuNc1BVs9QEyjc8BxZm2IT7R3FXEarkXeK/UIHrQGObP5ZXam6VYfYB8UvutvglV@coaYaHXEXs1b@HVC9uz6LGcsGdLER23@kvtF0uB358Y7h@8jbM9u@967Jie6wjUHQEV@HM5T4dpaZuOSr3sYfMaMeRPnphnqNnvuv1coZs04bEy1yejDop@8f5QIRcIKV2/RUj5GpDr6OK9UrSfJUdnt2UQrf8a4cTZkHFNLbtMUolBndWpg7YBjgguT9mDVIFCakneh7giYhzLuTBn/vsXqD1WkdavPYYz0qhBwcMAxQIYxiOuZf8isWXWx9b@MKF0A2z@tkSEMvesb0F9Rc8bWcqMlP6RIfRU6sNFVKc/sSbW0rbGYfOVhcuI17QzPhyplEjGphgCwFEHXPMS@HojGocfhDVW1fi1VpiY0Gq3btdmFoXaEBTwIbaen4LhKRpuhug6k@FCri400Jyj9STrDf0i7bYXsEOXj5VDhVuUpQUV3bPoXtto4o08nHlWyaRSKaHDhIZyFj7WNabSQdhXNn8uREw285jnfnH4bhQyLo@DyBKe27hSBBmr2vbkuVhMOrZjjWf4/EBp2nTd/sfkFAjVto3aGCiXNId3XY7dUHfE6hQ2773wsM@j2VnVb8FrG9G8BPpgu3ldpofHmj4oN1UcTR3gSNfi5/oenNDI1W2x4HJu7Bbis3r7q3VJ0SGiawUtv7bUcQ3VbVp9k7@mucw6eEUtvRbeotAQo8A4aszHiudj/JFrQmk4A2LZbWio9KyBRZ9rFH2z/Wri@a@VnqYu3qucp5bVSk73rdYqD0Mb5IKDz4XB6ZCyNHYdaGKNcQIhNlX6OEVV2K6SwP5w4lIiHwzMrsX3qFgnKed9FjhNh7fs5sblvRclPjWnBcHmPcyrWQIK1Zk18/z3UoCPZy3I18ng9h63a4W/hd2gH1DaV82NvVnFOj235/SsHp@QHnytKhzAj2O@p8g61AHrbg/nyA2HC3Pnw/Tsu/3@h9ATRSMXlK7bWYrTPq6qxSVhHwV3ZjbBQbxu7b8zx1x2oGFlqelZE6iXPHfsDi2VvlZ57WNfD3@ukqH@6Pcv2om0tqkPFPHfvyj8W9uWXdMdD4f0agz7E48eFFSlxdC36U0dPueFZlu6o672xh00NWGpiQkxNOi@XMQ07XGrh4vQOWdbXbfZ6tm3Id20zLFjnyX9Xh/@@UFtV6SMzdT7aK31bSDvaKYhv1TC7sf4OliV6aIDiVdrgWGNvrKsk47We6tD86zl8Q5RNLES9gmHSiNfFV6i5fSl1xN7PAcamiQV9PDykQk0rMJdTMtYqVnR4ou5GBbTNVZyKSnpqJCrVgoUHn1l/9LCBLpQEUun@WMVQuFUEkahCS8fQ24xqYg6CO1Q1y3YL/DXwmyopZWc05t0vZsCk/fYt0FFw8fqbguaJB3qtYY6y3TEaxWZjX4SV0/CuwE618RaO6ySXTuuQv70vmq6Nrwa8IKsm6zsQ@vbQ48/mdpZORonJklBW/z6kCGnzWx5Y1pkTNvq8FEQNN2mIg5cGqcFHURt4Zg@dqKjMOeKFxdcjtsFoa722dyz73eV2rJ0/tHy7A/qTPWLJ1bXxEncj@wxzgJdwhXEssvmLd0K@2sT07O/NoGUrWI23AqCj0SOwnsG4NcSeI/Nrt16uJARAZKCwGIKKX8tsD9a3cyLi57t4RyqwLCmYwpZjjMxcl0D2g1LfF7vug92wZgXIL6@cqnvZd3r7nCGy9BmZFrXs26PqZdVvFc1HVfNLluLxMVkMJx44rUcB5qlFe6FHpyRvXdhA3D1NYhW1jP74@U91aEuV9DCRKU4N67Sxr9h990u@0YhxUBpAyUMlfMljHMPquenODVo5CzhRIr7A0c@saNDHfGEvYa8tdJMtR17vL43ZzzGaUL@GxPDaw5c@pB8hE/t7sdCUE@WU@TR7br@fM3zLfU7cN6xOxm1LDQGG5mEmwUiVmvPn9aMS0Vc3IjlItxKWzt6A9Wh60zG6mjirK0VcmtrhRKbFnIhNmCxr@0/fqaEuYGmgd@mhVrQ@Jt4/dnctHLOwDUmsx1QxFbL0UXfflviPt936YjmIN8SZhc3h2qRuL7vLmvvPJ2NrPEHN5hA@E8G960WjhzeGvcT97HruFAbDUFQDo4svpnAwlyP5QEx2CNcLg/0ad8azTGBXVEJcW3DHFpNyN/@3PQhdREHfN8cmyuqIuobpPZfYLqVV@x@0xq9ok6/kHlVk3YRoYfWlNoWqxmGl0F13GpxlRj74xbKyMKIjTd0XYc/Sdqm4KU/Xi9VoCqgx4ePlWs4w3@hX2Bp@2wxqYfnfKKI1ea7XaxK68hqun3@XDMtybH5tABzZFte8hFunkB2uQxTQfvy1sqQ/FoZMm8agSZ7bno0Tr@8qTEHqU8/YhZQzxy1XBwJE4Y1E3RCOx7cIqaDRQN87kATCD8FiWW2JmLvxdvQ6g@aA3qsbDCEcvPIauJyoyZtEzI2pzczk/cMiT0SQpO6gp0FfHGFhTrHYk@hNaLcXm0ttKMWqWoP6UGSeuVwOc3XUR3bar0xsdfMJXrN@6YX3CHNySdkXNFXHSpG1IucNGkJ/dKStDh7DRSavqWOeyNo8yfH67q3/f1bloyHTAYWDjIvjsKsVF1dr0eJdZePpwfCdWSpYu9AkCXBPoJcP1R3V2qeCB7@h/e@moRKuJHL@HuagOi6fQQfkJ@MHPH6EA586nrjjj09BLxx3cEqcYLJykIQePGSgaatVYmA3HMmfd770A1NvRq0qTmm0v61qtoncT22VMs5V2mHuenNFLl8NVlyFzdDHVttVWywgCMN6iN/YVngTbyXDKCGZSPO99STnLDTXEbMAF1G3AtfMoC@5Y7VoUfv5NB7evDo8EQbevrS@mm3h@sxbuhxCzs2GIVUqEvqlTkKjXfyGWlt2xsn7x3r6t6jAw09rKA3H9FQ4YUjcwuvlf2eYutRM2mubAWhqzVeriA@PHn8KD5f@8lie72RO7CUsPPe8XEC17Z89Xipczj0AygdHXe6MvjBvq4rS9j3mUOjg6uk55KYVkE6saA1Csz4kG/4cqty1XKHVvtkNrQ@h8oTJbj3gdHnVibyiXlud7EUsuJKQlFBZUUtl1FCk7OhsW2Ngveq/DyzhygtW/RK8tfK6SioOaSTo/Ry7WHdiP91LYalxEyEjwukp25y69hWoWR0e2hKmt7fFzFd11fR@djsQL6y7MrMWvSwbHy4755/wFCyJRovamCljoGrVPvWqeR5dQCiO4kP7J4XlmBsrpwGsw5AYJ1bWuAvLGdmOiqNZa1TL0oQGie1rfXyDesDBqSCGT7nuCH00jG@YFY9i7XIqNwS8ckoFGRv797BbQGOBC3X@/r0yTP21PRwd5P1HsMYWx@A8VwzeqVivxVurbdyOLU9AlDGWnjd4fLyXGLH5qjtOrPp7YNwtLgVq3barDiAhV/kyerbU3tZXdXi/VpPl08zui1uvo7DnS3oweFdbwSg99/5Z7qeStGeRvjWU/zzlpzxCziLocmc4UZ5YaeTg0A0tFBv0cBCWdoafWRNcToK7w1e1qhfWr/l1tR9eWV1dbLOrbDGLbMmvhtuaMnSWkpfA5BLQr746GjihLfD9RJiQwO@ZpCv4vI0f8/iWMyJxxVlcVv88Jo1vloLN03jC63A79u3bEOspwKHYImZWMWFeyuBcmfh2keJQODiuphTqejZItvBzelLILoVihGsSnwLGz@yGtu8FKujSiX9CleIySWZidVrwY6UfFdFAIz7wUGimHqms80xuGz6a6sY7QvO3jLSB6EC0rMp@NKS4cWuZbHoDHDavHx68HT/@GT35NlxLVW/khWxtJLj5jgQm7/o9pN0W4bEC7oBn/E9VmlxZh@ioz3LUY/0/HQxSNm1pFUWkjZPlLyDYTYvHSeZpDWGSfUK8FNlHhu5QqWBVhy2n2LKILFEtMSX5vWJpPImBy1TnJBpJZZaFvHQ9DxIlnC/fmoCubJ0Gl15xGJbTCjdXddtixg9i91@@TE@2D149Oxon/kIzrnmwm6Pe5Vilu@airJYtSCfOjZNV6iwqAgShbyqVKIPokCYqBZlJVrZSTuWAqODN586uCZUhN5isU2CDxSMBpmS/C/fTF5FNZx5p4DfqI9UlAnKowd2gqu1/uwnbb6jt79Hg380yGhAgofWwktiJeaKdZhIUSqZw9UHhNAO2rTkMti6e37oikQbugNXXtD2Ste23lFoNwx@2ovYGcmPiBjE3wUYu3BwlyNof57buN6S49DBTYcWWRlHfWmjLY3t4uknwPPMpF3lAfWJM@Ybe4htACLAR1ogURJsk5Dle9DLIY/R7Q1g5abVtR3mOaAXW@MSewV8ht0kJb7oV1Wr0RtBfND82Bu1Nx70Qx5v7FLkJU/Hyfe/9t1kt8zAPE3dg69fEV8dMP8qN79IYl7f3MloHn8YCdx9TGDNIw9ojvQOHfTi8MXVc2Lhhku@qGT2ALLmnCiN3nkM/KmChJ3DidU@h4wCFoNcEouqeXzWqB7D7c9KySSyEQ45aTSR1JryWR3XtkHLZXMZPQlIquc@QNq3uIsr1jhARSkB40vn9rDysgnstb3NZFSzrEquzHMzuem8SMsvA0Q3wa900UPkagzCQJB5CHCrimBQn8R1BYOiPIrqURRFbRcqGnLHCgm/HUEImcWAWJxGFm6EO8UTf8ajmb@dXxNP0Qntab8pAKk6VDNkUmRJrAN@4o6BZRZWQPN1wDiriVdquE@Wx0@0ol30kAe1m6VpvnzN3zxflC8Nyz0HlU5drx/DeSs/RxDHCKIkL2PZ2gt2Oj516knOmwzY9EeCZcPM7ID5nyS7K3iWp3v35h5qses7oCGx2N1jx0V98gEkhsWMpJFO6jllnqRMZmmSRIpENJAc3NnhLUQHognERMuyX7lDb3dv/@Crh0@Pb@wTRj6j172BJK9ux09VLVGrB4ZoOFmLWXLvQfL48b0HfkbMkc6FJDCoLyIl@rqUzJuJCHI@7fh60pZheD11qzF@ztcmXsc3baxDjQLdwENPfUS8NPVPfUAT@K9HbhSWUSubXYfSHF4yBHqPr766gWpMubyq1berp04kepMTlhSEFxFtCwsBmE69rc0kMvvNxGHCgpPnTvDMHC9cFtPLy6K8mcbtanD959g9m2/UIyxCDqH0@tGAiJS0pO91Zek75Gr3fDspg5@Mxze2CW/nEUI4l1pH8RCoE/@QPZQi883wxD5wPWis9e2m5G@jwveD87etCraC41ugxBRJbKnOI46JY/empalG4/wxBaUdwUqwdVvL@fAUCQo06mtPJ9BofOoO@Ra7NJ5z3/JNRy6I3/sTPjBssa9OBuCvQ68ji/rWQHKrEBgoGQ1Q5foTSAmxs9w0jnv3QXw13F9OJFwbtLOxqaL1rGnb7oJsjykJkGif6HqdBbvPYaJptzknKlOezXNhbVH8FNfUhcn@UVsQTucImDVTs522NY1FL6JKqQ7xo3304vl5VJGX8RJthSj2Bmxf3xMxQD@vr5ck5liUTn/DwWXSoli8KSXA7jpgvpmPf75Hsaj1PImOaaqgLn48Hj0CI6gRsc7AHLLYxOEbHmmMPmOnMSdBO8SoVb5nmsPicWoiwYscNEYhO2Ti9XfMdGYslqwAE6Ct57Tx9cYespquaXUwUyQK28Rzd/ZA48LNQxQJmrUQpERgK8hC0HAAjHgh0TiDQxh0l3BPlxFtG7XEmY4hoS4IF2lCqWbVOyx0fNKi5igXiyWRoYtSsciA@26KQy0JYG/IOV@XB@qKzQmAZtCg1aTIXJDflHgRijfCEXkodjUAdCKhfQ79zQ4YwJrvQtjqjfCO7TtQVnB/ltKzkweNgpKUWbA7Qndkt7GLjG/VGzTaxOEKUEyTC16jZd5G@xSD4bZXDb79Au7K9IAKjHxNpEbCZLh@mOicN3V9LdeLgCIXwGcGKwCxhKThg8P93fzByiVuy4X9z3@Ox5XKsc2dXLrRP49Hs6kyPPRylmXZJ5unqrpZM7Kpyt3NummOT2VmJjNb98@tXqd50E2eyjJLs0wyuWXkXp8N9dzWi5r2elqXa4VK4qz@9Iw9ffrFu8Y7RZ6ez@TTGMtH2N7hW1mHBERKeVZkeC@96BzBpdeaVrocBbinp3gMqZyXk8latA5/cnoJF/dUq2pVbaf@7p1Sy0OaprPTCJ7uxw7vkjO1k6iryTCUY9u2k@x06LXbcLs9Vufn00b4FY/HVCYs1Bq3Y4Nph@ymu1a3O9k3Z9zejkzw9WAswj7@xvPnz9HwnC725kiE59CZH0epYWYjzEgZf/bTjavE5dPG9p99a5C0NvB1iK/vXj1G87Ge/WRj45N79zKZBFCJm59@4@nXd3d3M/cT2ae17E5GTW1s/@mfbGwYxraR3Kh7nl6P1s7OvpCNVEbW/uzH0cbTp1/zPMwWvNJMByM@C3DrqFOdsTdwnXUY/sn8ph0ym2hudt4wI/ImAmwdmdGvEWG8FFZISwpfG0yv7uT/6/cPX0fGkaqRfD6C9zjyOpIrRLgRDPCV9r/OI9XINnrLXUVmyUqlAsb8f/13EL76VYCDLrNteFSzPqzcLFJVKxTkbaSaA4NuGBDv//XNb97S7XOX1eCSM3lD3qnDtUXXtoR7UqmpZPKad71wR7/DmDPujS0XXzZ/OfBiZtmBVvdRLR6P1zUVLq1BgZK6bpxSh02Ytai/JRJYlxm3YSG7OZ8IG3B7HiGeAqYivuJmYUGsxi2eX/f3fMlVfv4PfR1JkdzGXet@tQqi0KgaW9U4XRunpRInf5LlC7Lr3sUereipHGUv2SNB7KqcKhhyIpG428DDn9kUaapOI3MCMk4jFlmgbITNv1jYKsL8YGzu52P97eP15//bn//gz79Pvx/Q/R9x@y6nbXeSWxz58yq/WLUqV0fy5Sl93GWpUqFUSDbY1Wlsq1atHzE99enbaDYdPcY0kid2qvg9nJHgqlbx4aOBX9UIt6ly09xOuFSDD/IxD7LcHxOSySdqBKpgMctJrZ3XOW4cv5tX7S5kk2zki3K9amSNQ8g6XaaMK7LepsfciEjRDlwb8KM/XDvYeSxs8LlBltyFvC65NgJUbr8WsJQitVqybtVBkWVVH8jdjdJGoZQrGZApqwGXV4GOnIeliZbXCpoB4uNdbYMdcV6vs7h/ncZvvZ5pWkMYyeDiraruNCJF/gGuqsQil3DV323V3gHriqhropzGt9V6NS4wgpfWuFuPq1dXNe1FvFwW/@1qYCzTxU2QkPqVqm6/AFi1m1A5UHpqjRfbADa@XduuuHt0aw0ksVp/Ua1tL4YVwe/ejaOMvQsAqpt1Fs240Zx7lynx@KaqbtRWpgEA12OgBGxDBl5tX1WvattXV9vb8N@m55V4g@3V9o0/vebXCj9zdyo2p7Vk9TR5KtimDt9asoo2WvIUDFV4gz@ohqQIKCZTKbLFtiJDpufTYGJWSd8y0sns9JPcPqhGtbqKLZiKWtNz2brKJdVLjZVUvue3XsgpGoqihttp4DI9jb2UIi/ff/m/4H36/svfx3ofimVRiiS3sHlQ5K0EeDx22OPHj/F@7Djwh/sxvxy0QYvHaOfwh8N9@H4Ca26DxQGEApONQk5uxPWZwSLbci6PYuGXblzRaPQfvTSK@ShvQeNytpceWP7Ssusf/dKqS4q8LWI5b3mMp0mKULmHvIDyU0XjJT6ar/H36A3@Xo/xd9LC39Fr/LGTN/g7GuOPPW7i76mHv5PX@Ntt4u9kgL97r/H3eIy/Z138SZEKaNubO6l@qpXSz/QzMNgsNWKpXqqnt7EpkLJYapaasdTA1dtgsuCXApOd6rBUl6WclKPr4AiGMUuN0dSBVxd@HYAygp@NI9pneqrFIJY@AOXn9tD7LUgy5VSqQRtSfmmBXqzpWkrL2XXc7bwm141igWlIYq1Re3kareM2mkYxw5oza@P0JYt4oFOXI8nT0yTvHWBGpowbo19dNRr7T@43GkmURaeP3cP5//BwEP5c@x8cuo8P3YEL/8PDw8fMqsbvxtW7cFWq8W3x2olUyzunJRULri8rIsntndNqWkVzLg7F30C7@Edec4jwrm6cSlEGqspFmRSi8sV5@aJMhuATDI1y4EF44wawLAtFCmzKvkZ1Adf5BVniA40Xz08DEzckn1@cYsMAWnzBHzTO8Od/g7/9/67/42csVquDghO7vNqO0aXgT1Eury6vxLOqxGLiI7YNP7SAbwxyeVVFI3m6BFMtptSVqytuB8@Yss0BVjGO7SoFnnuE0h8J4qR4@SP23/aNcYvrFDfcNudD9aen01RKKTf9DX5xmMp8SyOmSpmOa9ls1vT6n/6YtnHeUchTNlMu61uMfxgZo1zO@F/5Qrlc8D82Y7Hizaua2tFzoOFkMopSLsPHjg82BZ8B2AKA9T@yANXyzBaV@3Lk8uCQNjgGMZGNKJgiLhhiKdoHHY/UiMol@c6dmDiqc2dXuXPHKKbevg1shkOw0hesGo22PWo00D799q3ckGnovJiF71Th7VuQZVHFHcWe4EksEFFM1dknRpXiLLojIEQenJmeNOZY9EzPHI9HsTf2MCHj3BxPVuighFTKHZ1Gf/a9b33rNFqpyKpMthkdAWAsLLu9nctUq7kMmHMFoJS8ecnPDOnGi7pytZmUOTWYvBmNCCe9kFe4bIyiO1RxbKcKBdzDi11eRSjbWSarxEC6KqBpXUXwx631YpHbs0wuVogXxa@yobAqKAH8hw3UdDyzld@6W2f0my67UCSXL62KflW5tErYz3dVbolj8HAxn3XnTroINC2kyqdSo3F/92S30ajIsoz1ITzQkoS7hKfvDEfRGmV4tlivYfrqp9FoqXyXmEMvZFkkWhb@1CjUEqxQJDJIdgdX6kLaJV20/jckg974kERn0AZY4kn1bH4/fbS7t3@SMLZBpzEe7O4ljONn9yI6fmbn3@Scxu@j/d37h88gwNNH@7vH@58efL7/7CnYe@xifvkSWDzn77BpyfcFey69Gr0xLcu0JpbVuJhMLl6zV7bdsIGw/Ylt2253xDyrYVnWELz5Vxnulu2Zr16ZoyFd7P2PvvP@R//d@9/53vvf@c773/nBz778wXfg/gnc3@Pv7/3bYhafP/vyn/3u@9/@HbD8j3D/Edw//dmXv/lNftP3H8P9n0N2fyzukD9@SwDrV3725fd//LMvf/WHcP9Lcf/w5v1rP11@/@Dbq28M9/3fXe/ne/8O7t/jsHy/3/ttbofvG/5/m/v71R@@/41/z/9/Kn5o/J33v/HH@BAf//SHf/qf33/rPxhG4U//zftvf//9t7/1/tvfff/tf2y8/81/o6fCj999/4M/@Ks//L2/@sP/if4/oefvfcj//Q//6V/8r3/xv//FH4r7p3D/ezD99C/@AzDs3/7Bj/D//T/42z/6Ef7/53/1t3/w63/7K/@aDL/FDf/3v/y3/PnXv/af/uZffPevfvrNv/n1n/7Nb/3BX/0fv/p//uZ/@uv//vf/@n/8Flr@1k//6o9@5S@/9Z2//PY//8tvfbni@Z21zy8/wP7LfwCbD8fzQ@B8SLo@1ubLXwifvw815rEAnwB3/5P3v/nLwOC/wdj77/wEp6TCveL/E0MnPz/hX/8fMBg304wuKTDB/evvv/M9JNH/ACSCf0Cv7wYfCy7847vzDyDrv7gWKGKVFivPglGIb0ELY6tYFBVo4LxNIX/25T//cRDFLy9CXXCDGL@LkmrB7bso497/6Jvvf/yP3//ot97/6FewNlMzxcRuQtXX9z5DFahmP8Afesx9iD/w@MUXEP80Tn2lahy/2BfC8YsvvpCmb5M4B/ruW7D9gqz4xbgTuDHh5LsJe5yqGvbDjSnfuInWb8NRIxniGG2cVIEtX0/Jptk0LjCaYlccvsEePE23yDjFJ9mi81TCx/w/N04lFkc//MJjY3wjGUQ4EQU3SlmIJj6d@vQixYlxZYX33E5pGInizRQZpmA6jU@hRQoGiCEOTvfirFKpxDFgheMDnxy1aoERKvF4BdKNoXmYRKOAIKb3CAqErMSPWGOrMuUB4wiv6pMjLqHVkawbcrxQuQ8RVqb3GcJC4AT25ctKtVCZVhHcO06P@DR@j3BCYJX4tPoOvisEM469SvffASqFSjxeLWCEmEiePYkGz6QsJY7SHmdxkQfwpi7au4x9IusFmQ9pbCDBuG98xue@d2iQbQfcT@NbIjn09410bxHBNygqEQvj7jukKu5w7RE9AFxV1TSNwY0DdzvsLjhPOag4RQuvOIcQJ44gDggsgA0xL@KUv3H6gPgjla2PvuJViadmc3NTilTltHxIQzxxaLWPzkr83I@3vGlUYnKuKKO1RVO/eeqszafU7bB1fwueOvz3N2hGdpyVCa3NKPbuRRmPj30S5/fdu1vsE0g9ved2ElPjaTeDveuY0O14XDYg1qobl16AdJOAfQnQW0mbVmhgKS4lEoxplQi6scPDQ4EaWbyoSHHgfiOt4zeOBEwmkwiE0LSElkiIt0ZvstCEQSNX8dY2kebUG8kMI1OG9k2ZoRULN0d0aLei5bt37yCzaFZG6QBalExM0DAyBXIEC740tN@f@SsHjExR4s1ppuf4ydwxOrhPYYrEYmxLkfj8XY6Ef8WiRqEQRZMCeaLFtvz5Ojld8jsJqY8wCMHbeIWs4jvuHbK9w8eP95@cDOt1Jll0oqLVGI7cluV56wRzDMPtPrnPp/cbxRyiEanVMOaTkoFiSdovpUhoHtw/OjguMU4TkUOxAJJSpg5gQYqiLkWGw@fbETGnQcYjPlz5GJ@lefpjRjGNEVbLUqRlYbMEGA7/rCw99rr33Cm05ROynNBz2ERTqAuVSV93S6XKOz2Tl@BN3xOGm1HxlatQOnESuLa9TUSTqpcqdXujETI4J1WrYnIQ06Xq8f4JBDg5ZLqR0hi09C8zeSOTzWSNdC6XzRt6JlfM5LKFNNQ1uVTWMPRiJlMsFPNXUvULNtUQVxXM/Urfcrrj3iZOyZFPU3KIHpu1VAJ/RjoNT4CY0LP5@sZG/1JFBE@JLS5xbtUVfF6qSIGvwMWkr0jsK2AFF8SBE6aYmK12cFgWU4Zwj4gYnzck61ko3Ip0CozEwUnD8FUeDqH8QGs/dEuRjW98Y8yqVWhlqwcPpAiIqR7z582odlvracRI7cnIItcuY237cxtPftHatjfsmzMonClNilxdXXUA0sEDHFSlTx6ijc@rFtk0wXw1NaX///oFr4iqVqXtYRUYcjs5BKMJxsx20gRjE4zZ7WQTjDYYi9tJG4yTalpPbScnUE9I23yHJYYLOCvy2Jrihm7cTq56Vr@j4QqBikwRGPK22LGwKsJVcamFa7YruMoPp8jHlEupXWm7LTptSmprTbc907zxrI9T6fvuqBIFdSzqO9h4gCeuzKrUWF0bukOoNI1sPl7TUyCj8dYLCSORTbRxIv7QHONCi51sqnRhO233Qvvi8aOH4/HwyKIp@juZYqlQr9VkOV4jaHU8o46XQ3VjA1jXMtsqvDuuM/ZUo1AvtYFlR5VKNLqT1vVSOlWQroI0SkAdRLwqYbg4IpxACl0KLi85rgNFausyTikrdTqdq1LCTNiX82/JvFT5FyT7Km4mmpfBZ1kN@YvbiRKbzB2vpJLZgRrlssXn3pVkI1uQy7Xy/Dufk8v1K@nuwGrbJk7EP01d3giUS8lXgZ/TFHpb4imHniDhPLnAQ3ynqSrNGKuBiKvvQ81Vq2/7e1Ah7xiGaqTVtK7qafzfYjDw/@H@Dfgb@IRQaUM6wXWYT0DSgSh32CPc8nrsshPXpdPN7lmtFT72eiZNjdsbuZ739/Bzz3TOuNN9m29@FDg9NPFYA29gj3srfDwbDnAJpzX6B4OwP2gCglTkyMM9eIz6rrvMQ549e7oilY@D7QaBGHy/QfB@dPDpw5PQ@2R/d@@hlGP3Dp/cv/bKCk9Z9mj/wUnwmeeuftBsAOLr@48eXf8UrwhW@th5u8Gyed@gSzi39g40ee4IYzY3N6bQ@Jwv@7K9YK4nX99Xkk78tWAmwxLetFiLr6rFNhjteCFUMT1flKQhc9wLlk@xttvvm3iyY2cDLHsmrnGxULno0wGkGPWFO@q3L@y2tSE9xuU0RR2Pr0MkpIcAZDBp0fJyeyzh/kltPHMRBwuaeGz8BM81XWEJL7RC48ju9kBMX7i@B6lpmgzuj70gvBW@xustxjwOsrvh0r/pXYpIqEOaYzNSKN@5oz8dAWdXC6lSqWtBK2PoetX9KXAXm7BnwO/mCMXqZpJtZuVcS37AtEbE3AK9rWvXXK8@PGIF7MJumenMFqjROmoioDuaVj6Cohg0J5YoMNSiUMOtGaBFnaaSZsZty7JTfgPK/LDqRVNX1pX1OpeP72SgRoCqBhTBcumv/8VPkMG3kiDLIros4xTgDV3SSGM1ioVsoZg2ColCsZDJ6rlsNqEbCWgQ5IsQW0ov6LlCtqgnCpliOgMqILhmi3kpwudXJbcIJLxLANZp4XFs26T0ar2qFOFDS@xNzFRYxAy@J0y2IIyMB3B7Y1pjuGVXZCPD9BSD9g5ANFmLRR482Es9eCDL9/ADB9T3UrLcxo9sIZXK35Nli1z2Clhpyy4PU8BdLeQx/0il7u3J8oQDwA0hZbmHH/s57C6RZRs/9nYfPMB4OvhhYHjwdsZd@Eff/8iDNwc/0mnqb5Hl1wE48LfLI8oQpvv4gXGiywPusgdusvypj08qBRCOuD8O4aGf1t1dWT7gH7u76LJHCc9yVD/Dj126ZBkYBwuPLHfB0B1BsZXlJhixCMlyC0ytmQl2ePgd7hrojE1ZnnECIYlkeUq@zdaZLDd8e4zm4cOHZm/ctrr8mo34uwWogYs9new/aH76abPbbY5mu/ufHqHL3t5DszObjJrdpgjWbMDlQhhwORvMrl@A40GjYfaXunwGLs41l8asYSFuDfM14CSuLkYyaOyByx64LBuV49DgGoDXJl73BvC@ZzbJxb/Ihd7TZlMuI6Oi3kgn2EKZocNkEwOzNXLL@D2tbDAWjUUTs1ouVS@TAxuAhpgqX9HRtTF8mtg@Vy5ntWklVa9MK3mDT@foxOTTqZG15cTGYEcvZksb5o5uZOLTEq40djtRFlX1HRbT72y9YbEnyo6RzpTk050dVa7p9R1DL5Ry@RdbE1lWSvjcSedL4DEVhdYrPpRavr6Tz4aC5PNxM2mU8nmlfAXkGEMV20Sp0ojFLizzTFEQXWxlQRL4wbkzSqdd7sSmiWmF48VmSnla0ct8QyuWugGrjbsnTlpjd8QhdgHcdCdVoqN5Zb1YkCH@ZDKmKCCZSIjAez5b6/nXTs5OTr4AmQXtV9H6e8rPeyyLz08f7mnQIBRfuOuh9gD1c3ek7aFgWXDhm/L5VicgVLWHUE@CCu/b4eqPkdvX9qfQJkcl33fw97LSxA5E2snDBTjH0PTlMePi2TJtY@G0LIabQtptZlaqYDLbLEZYMVO5oBq6Ua1WGpUBP123GoT6jNGOiXMwBx7HPVjSS8EvcUWEcGhUUlflZmUamQKcRoWp@suB235pxFvlNu4Fea9yDwOXG/Bulq2KhWcMyxG53NlxKoxNHM/sWE@tES5QPzjchGoIl0nEOsxSNtkpnUi8hwr1lVodMWeO2ZPJIGaq1aayaBX6RNLEvuYn@ZLW7eA491W5U2GxF0r5NXyONlmsrd1TdjLlduweayhgk3rZedlhBstlynRIWwwhQSEi2tBJv0ql@hmoOBzwWakEiIg8PgOYGBOAtdvkYCpD@6rcqvRZTGVTphB5MuVupYah3@JjW5XluqrW3talqqo@l6pQTsuziFnxJk3aQJilmrqRypWnYKfnM@UeZKz5YloeVYaTkVXuw6foCuHLk8wykBOoBmDevI29/@VvKttqtsLtygTqbR@0iobWqEzLDm5JAixRSVfAIV7LpBLZAlT32XwCKmQD6v9cIp3IJNQ82kJtDG1FsNRBD4j1YzJjciI1TWl6Qrf0BJT@l3b7JVMSZzFQSIhk8DF29/GAY7CBTEKupE94m0yJG1t9BrngMnNbJTYFSVHGhAHNe2xoJ3oI6sgy@xRCUVSW3or1N2PoZ/NkMtyv1Uul/enwa@AUU1/v5OL5VPyNopRjG0rFs15L1bJURalCqR5uAM@KXiLmTQY1yOPxpp43SrVaE1OYTyXSqTQkz2687W7LVbmeSG3kdMihK0Z6DOMCg@syc21kbtdAtRpPC2d60ShLGk2IoBj1mFFcta5FkXAqngAoDYWwQwqz2KnsL9CLRaN5IxpVomXsT96QRTcgSDh@8DiI2ugdfUcG/UkuyUUDPcwFJa3BSoVVqCsJ29osU5Qil9LV5dU2tDuTNDMO9ES2QSZVq96VIiXGQI87Fbt8JDcY@9gJd/Ht6gv@PsU5uQBXoi3FQF2kaTCWjY0l9jmuN91hUUDMHA1qhpGu14w81G8gM32vhqGXsbc8gpN/tSpQ3rsE/LbjVVyq8Rmbzcy46lP2DmPd@KZEiY5cJ/tuZbd7tFv2v/awv@5UkmW5HJUjl9FI9Ap@UuQurQ8x@PoQFgmtEOFzSlsW0OddhCQG27v0e2tKeLBFzCxx@VCrK@@e2P3LQlrlDX8QWFdXkc0k5YiYZl/@7KWRhTxyXH/ePTSAUBWHqiubxd7GSPLl0PuGUUg/Pjh07o8eWIxPuy9kGnI1wlK6irPYyyVhm@XTbuViwZCNs0SE3Y2UI@xMjeolmprPhsfFF/kXhRePnx0@O3wgRU433m642BPNfLKwd85XvwYeo@lMlLHTSmRayZTFzKdqVdW3DdxAJ8/w9PiOnlNTb6ucfavkkDPA5f0v/zAz3S7AtwHaawmyMBs3qlV9y2BKZPj@y9/HjRMu9z/ffcSinjljf/cnPzbyf/cn/4rmE0Wvyh71euYj4BONei4fubwcXl5ewcXdspF6hCOVyStg5l3semQ@@7@UNM2tfDxj3HXKSeFXz@tKxFMjYiAhn414b4WTkSqAk9/TT1ZyDrMgsn9kZw397jYyhR4sGmLzAWXLKwJXFB6/fMsYfLSq7W7XNsiUTLLSO5Vtv1O32TvsKX@nbrCXlSqO7uq41MjvGt6qVqsIhUWr8eRWlBlZcKtdletxRr3L0Bp8YW05W6eLHH26wYpFB@wtb0uMRZxuedDk23LoZ215Hnz6X9bWK4/JOFqSTLbbtKPMtsWyVcj/rSSgc6q8/@XfNIzc3/3Jr71tvG18YUDLrVjM6Ubk5/rPfw4e1qxx95td1HOOi9HREDTX2IqTjrUWtBTx@OsO4/79xhs211BnsLsONNjxSzpHPYeypsE3TmrHyNsWLoFNkNZM25ooZUkKtEvSikfdVoJgsC3chR7KpnQpfQWdoDJlFRCX0lfmoMBiANWn22p4/cloSFPqYxROryfYHQgCMXwFN6XaoKW7QuaqIKaSWzeDcpQ9ohrpRGxgeR5ucQW1iPQVCCJ2DMPDdU1cZY4@bQeEvIZeCE9yaNcg7jrE3ecBGmQbo9RzDwnGseOBHNCcpa@AMkBUsEFHYPY2eCiDYPkKEADSEBOA7TrbZmmFXdrxeHm@f9YVzk7GXdNMf4WrhMEQWhtXVPuBy@gPrEBjxzNqkC9EDoN6FrL0gXAYfPS0Ajo/BqcvVLpoCfoHgwJYtN1LjJLG7tyZY1Wp2G2FUYoQ/pk9xG4pygdnOa4AzG8vfdIuyQmGO5OVfduA7YDicUIXuE7lW5KVQ0GZjJ9XkgT/D2Za5MhrWUUOZUyAyC9eKlpAMgiMZOd52GLbFaYbeYUFyLcA9xYhRZthBY3A0@knmvGF73gFGP484u8ADdLnJNzVJ/j2@hJnBtXeBLffxY1uuDAQS5P5VjYoxQ7GfuggFCTF7pPvjj2CBgqN3vr7YsXSuoLB5vuIER4039jIMJz4m1XwRaHQN4O3iTtAiXg2aBeLlgsZ6g1dh7aMou0tcE41cATIKLHzDkd74lzgdu0ibyhwGCOPdt1BzkeMaQssOueOwuJwaHMErVifNglmdTXWGrSZUWQxYjTaIcgJwCkUiBBugraLNG72rQGgdGxZDHdN8krJZBe0okmTtkl6bANf9R7YUJU4XlIcKZi8sM/s5AluN6u6HVChxaLzCCpSWPz4yKvYkqjvumesb59ZvAc3trBk32Og74PSmgDKzm8gbAk7i410gqXAOcF9wZ2HV54bC4lQ2I3YTLn5TusbsQbm6Fuqk@wRHhd4bjoh@tL1VhJNXG/m@Zt@0NYV8K0FItcSy/0rUVxpHOxjIYntSyq0c4aGvfjDGDQ4/W0/0Ai6uHXOsLEqYR0DQrPlL6DHUgyp/QpVAFT2oGThDmDjUQm3fQBMRu1YC4qeEPAO@4SlDQk98j1ZxP4pAAOzvrIIHdwgKKbDG7chYzS@WAvkCpTOQRvccMGxYD8M73M3mml3tjl7sw0BDisdiqvCeLHwP7KhDywdyM@U9A1wzAGGSzDZiMlxABuXFZmDDsJfD865XSJZUmI3ISUYQhCkBiikKvjnibLQvuoSONwzPb75ptgr7OLiQqNN6yYjW7M83Gvcw0NSk8OuDTqxmxxbg6E41cnG0/wE3LlJ5UcM4NG5O1M6tLZ4Z8bfktTxKmKeRCza8aJYOZ7jVtrdAW12g7vMeMRQD2zahr8VE1M7OP8Z9cSlz38l5D@1EL1CIIwhmGlilmglAFii2TpLdC7aZeFwTgUSgEMuWr4lbhQ58j8Gnm@yh53AhzumFQz@d7N/RqOYAEnmXafzqHkKfZ8z/1N8D@0pBHKsC7Y7GpmzGLkr6BsZODYjtYfNoNonFzBCNcMu@a6F9rQ2qy8EnwbBoVLzmzxshDvZSJfrgfItLNF9yt2n4D7l7tN5pH60tWmdq2RodYXJQa7HDdB8nwhm5vu54ts9zl0IMijWTOcg0Odswe4K7laFQvv05l@QjxWfMYAnhkBwK5asvTitndYdz7rYqseTXWB2mQgBOQ6ga3Wi6UU7MCP1@@f9oestWDm47x3USgJvtGr1BDdwXsE0BhlEjMHpZeNWZd2BGHznCoFIMEBAPQwcUTXYHcdspRzsmUqOwDg1eU5jjlhNIFMn7Us4CTtQlzjpOWHDgOohQGgfJAnQBBfmlxx@soQvHZ6P8ABt369Km@EPcMucaD0KlLxWVLisKVMmhbBSVR9NIDuqq5XrSfHdIStq15xCybwS@R9Gf@Oj0e9AuViOPTEsrzDKUrio4MQxUCFEcSGqsmollK@AQXLL7FsjqLn2uX4qamuIZivpNzN4PJgE7wKPy4yFMr@l8PyhNWWyI5cCVphVKpDEWYUXS14ufJJyggfBPBFs5jOCCM8FCMBILQ1miWDTcLBppcIFB5uuCHYRQnJKSE55EO57ugLJuggGrafgnGXMnjpopzhNTQZ4Oq9GQQ0aygzPzMTB6le4nReOUoo45zKHuEDwEKrYyGet@tLYayGkQ0LrGgBkxBsA2vyQqpJ0XeDpavAVyChOSl9G8S/BBlxWAIORCC7zLS9jAZNRGxgUfjlO9QCUXTlek2Sd@nXxl@K3nPAt/Vu/aZla9KkvWqYS137/IJZ1pGyogIa0Dz2VQYGMLZln4nTxBZ0jguc59lzQ6poXLostUbbBPukfTJ5s9t1mcmDiBBE8uiY4rlzx2w84JsLuDt2xOXYzmRJvNNnEdsvi520Gu@u40DQJb3ULul7btTwnOoZMbbldx/asBB6QzlV2i6Yr8E3KpbCeLIyuJ0miD5I3YxE05ytUdRsNPEyv0YjhxDOlFMxwpXloyJ7RqITtXzCFwoN4EkAPhzG3@cpqjZXbYeKuzCLYid06ix0OhWMUItllIMNaoP@Daw80GOa585Yj7Q@LqnRzHKOt8HvuwO2C1jfxNAlDXwN/MIeNCJnDIeGSYCY2aUuhvbmplMRaCVMRQT/76KDsMyNmKkF4YxHAAjESbHSdxkjZ0ZLoGiuj48H8@I4/Ht/jML7H6/GlVvh1nHnTvMIdPy7qdGwOATzO0UjfjgYmHeRW@wY6C6gE1qhX8QAfjGKbJmC1EdNd8LorvGsd4I9E8OXBV4D456vovz4D/eD7H5p9Jp4wejwDeTPAeYExOqTA8wc3Y@D9QFGkyJLoAta@/4FxgV88H@YBqhCgxpLgcnBrSyiYQ2h2e8GG6z7gW3ge51Hd4HuaXFXhjktwGp0n2JmxOovuN9pW35xZ7ZjwmQjB9VN8BA02klcflnAUdCT0XN7Wi0HdpQSuUI0j0bmn0gqWMRPnirKarbgXO@Ae6iknDA9W0w/db4hm7OKr8N5qaAdEo7jNmnNuY/fncDac8d2T@/xsCSFHef3DcxJXzt9OEKCD2DwmMY9WWSc@j2JBkj6gRgj8aotJxs1NfYi4b@jNPPw4Et2eUsjcUKCKn8vS4kkAy3PcXpfjIa7weZKPG30YS97GdB/McyFW48DmImzv46qQG5BxPkarFQtD5DZrc8x1bsgEtKN@OmdFrdJYIlCDkCTpxjY1t0m/UCRsGR/AGzucPoc3Auxa4wZnKD9t2KclDn1h5DIwhyGtRdiAkg5QQlTkJBdohHxJvhm8X14FcbZWxtm6EWdrIc6gBCxGGfIktRaiFLmA2bMuC/pWZ7xCOqMTtp3htU5sw@W45gh7Ky6jdrRkJ1j0PFoCgRy1oqX9GAjlaDtauk8GL1o6JsNZtPQZGOZlK/o2WvKLBXoYwScZ7qK9EOH43YqW9mLKlTQ2zyzPj1eLloI8BT87/JMoAqTAdIPWiENsjiuSOR5ZULGRUplgyDFeAptP1A@ToDsFf362B50RgI7Yx7lFnlmc6QuVRqjG4PFAteHvQb2kJJdEbb5/@IDmMwVeMJo4tPHCYQg8qOGR6KIw4oihK41owBsQRLlZWo4RC9VkH4iOiB04lDJ5MX6inkb6QDtG7jXwXJ9HQge6iPB@fi2C4Bn4YXhi4FV43kDHj44wwjFZZQlaSNSX0TWJwrxexEXkfjiHqK970RMe0et74blEYEMyHXQ4GpzDyIbucJFJyBWnxtvhMNQpxwslcu@1YCQVRMlc4UzWImUoGMKFX1mXnFA4RG1BBKFjLVXnpSyoF0gWo9Nc1oU0VV74AIWQzIESbrXO6LCc@8JI/ri4SVBdsaoa8sPyKElyLYpJCKzhFkATc8xjDxqv@7gx0Mc1X/2QU@xriSGAUMggFi5f3Y/Q312uv/sKtU@EaxEsU6yXV6U31eu1tew1zPvzaG9mIDom2H1lqXIUxDAnObQOQpr5Ol67oeLjlA@u5PNIA@jXtH2fbEGb4Ba6XW9bcFioJYzOFy3PDLA8M1YT6qZG0j/XfKVFw5gEHJ7wANN50tbjyhO@LIvRhfq3zf5HZ/BoMYPDmYfwKAGjayTnpXw0cWiWy7xsg9jmNihS9RLjgpyGS4NsnluCuKeh22DYFiwOG0f3D588@jpUuvl8XhF19GyOH5Za7GsN6nEOmSZHB/XBkmaLkcDzL3CwG7vj6TjsjVNHviFLuLAGZcCEWHz2E2VcEbIsJM@vlV0Ix/2GKCpgnc2LgbkglVDVMbHKtgVdx0AQaxzbMgUQX70FeieotabQSQ@NBh6B3GhQ9dVo4OSlRkPUYpg1/oi48vPIRnLijegIRn5MyYUk0dp9dv@QPX@4e8JOHu6zB8/2PmNfP3zGnu8@OcE12E@f3Xt0sMfg3n9yvM@khemReKQTNiiBrvetloVH7@H@aRlGkPfc4YzLndiewu2PzQF76LYsHKba9szB3R7/0BxrXOWh9qE5OsM@TJuO7RrYY5xvQWdOQTMWlZs2Lb3DufwM/DahTTvANu/AbdsdG/xK2PYd2pbnrwBjfRtyEOStvyg2wZUkPF6Kpg7RQXA4A@sCgpvgH8duAIzJ51/RKdO2xwNYbY0JwgXXR1PwZP/o8THDVf57h0/uH5wcHD45Zg8Oj@Dz6dcPnnwK9Dw4Pjk6uPcMncjj48P7Bw8O9nbJgiOQ0hius3818cZrUdDQO1GldYYj33SYePC12OuNGjy7MGkRoseiEwelj2327TdWO1qWJh6qL7jwkYYKWGxz9@jTz6HOZ9ZrHOH0h4Jp/oH8zKNjzjZTbJtig8JShfJWFsUVqj1VV2g8YjBjeOqBVaYl9TEyJ5gPnCbxtG2LyXs4RwX7vvnKeyrLPmiIaANgIyh/wkqF0Wkl0Whim0BWIbZW38W9E3lsfBKh@MCgd/2pJmWJKCbmyiBQXK9w4GB/kF4OLIDvwcIQ0Y5H3ANLBxbcA8twC1RFD3DuCMsKH5Px4QTFM8txi1eD4QMaFmb5wOKeSa3YgsCJ5xtlqcmC055wH4I@nUnDe3norDzTa9k2BfHIP57X0u/zgmHxk8JAJvKhRJrbBj5lEDYdHGoQ0974mZroCtyA84TMzthjsYqisROcHGQ5Nj8NqNs3HT4Faj51h3iPFXCnmYqYZmsHp@jQCpChSwyIJ3gt4hGEuy@0QutDw0HIezdiNMUcSTrJzp@CdhsC924g8IuAAUDqQkunRTUVrTVFMG5HsHLMc4Ejsd/2Xdg/sHN70rIWAohZW7FX9ps3iiByYqGd5M9TJOwgi95YI1AraSiz446gjJNYpXNHUAq2eu5wbPM8jC2mgEacqJoD31ixQWwvK9WF2JAO12N0XCcUaRO4eEWsTWDKD4mVOJ6PnQfia34IJXA@VMJ83h2iYzbxMO352FkCB5EuLOx@AUWYxsqx83M2Jky4/inNZcc7hufYFSrV@/dO1XcvE3iYHRcL/PxIf9Ih3sCYGBcUDxrnowmLI9S7REnzDyHyJk0MLebgCWmJpdwHBu3Ang3turuNcuDGpxvftMc1MtftyfLt2woPpaJkEkeKer3YXLolWM2PMkFh6kxMAQnJTkAWZH3Mt0kQzEBe38V1MZgLZaCIg3IE2@3XjvgRIsRPXXPSAckiTloU2R3AV1iVZlTMD57FlS3h/Ei@iN2rxKtKcj6hhIXIGfNFdMKHrCtKaFoK1Vc3wN1fDw7k94eDK6zFjlcPHwXt/lpoH4WbGl8Ni1dLIVgfDvbdGrC8cvuFwELaE6sB80ryJrSA0wPmTGxGgtm062N8eSPvqOwBGKx7sQclABqKbeLQELW/U3GMB1DCYOYK0fHJ/f2jIybz9gmEBbmHTYa2EIMIe4M9nc@2tR0SdlqgNAWN5UB58m0WZrT517rCvJR4K0SF0EESgh6BsJgfsdyxp1zqiZqFVAiafU8C0afcInaXvgzyagLwFbQBAdl5poUSKC1NZoRXPrYXngQu6JbgunF4Dj/NsOZ1N55fOJqFAYXnBJldXFmyPP@ec/245MfDFSzcAQcT3AZNGuobaCccQ8RD8Khpizm4Jlv8LMVJ9lzBjvi0w4lfqUUN@@/PUMRIXAnnunBIrAvl@P8p7tm22ka2fEZfUcgkWCDLNgmEYExiwCTu4ZKDIWmWIW5hy8anje22DNgdmHVmHuYHZt7nE@ZXzj@cp/mKM/tSVSrJBtIrs1ZnrWBJVbVr165dt30riRrvjxfUNocMEnEZ8NHSUyayRTMkqCmevmyaHepEi146vgTBJhNvtHtvcgUUv3go6DvW09E6WdQbcnOsLRA2NYXlBUpnJezC45leoC30WnJ6SFYFs@2TVWX@f6riVSJWk6L5zMaoRIC8trr66jnYyVao4pkfhc1rSHL@HF0P4HwfgQwnIYn3gXMrh65KjxjgCdKxab0aMImCsNWZsabE2k6LkYkf4MJyIUAGI4TjJYHJWh0xTuA2GzqvSCZ0yjLVBmMI64byqJmi/sPT1eGE/Gx983@8Ph5smAlNBx/QKv@gPwyDyCvPiKJifEL/1fi3YDjsUTb2Z7pGKGlyY3rS2Y687djglVuFiaRvM1vSkt5JbHbrKlkDVULiRQ/vBUXpXiEp3svkC2ZT9yr7ZbFEkftaMVmkPbQdY@6Z7/SeQoDmYJJL4PJBPnwvwg34Dzi4CiSQibz50kQb51nciCKwa67RrS3SLFTOrflk77fCht/DkB6u/SIUtvsSCpIUtny058ySrOcKsfKAXDjopaGUa2c8m4rCNxToIqQ4CO5N/G4sWOipoSwln7jN3c/m13Nrby1qXc8dude1txfuUqNoC1h8/d51eDO8a/7a7l/dtkRXDP56OW5Mfv9NiNXX4hXUtfKSo7bm14pZCnn5Bv6ui7c54lyJ4DuKQHtuC@HxDXJCLIroHF6YF3x7Gh2aN9BDIsGlYulacSG62I2K17W1i2KvmCtc13oXBXTyGy0XR8v55TR@eAmrKMwxrJmvjS5wTTWlrkHvVuDFonQBnHQNEeQaAl8O/GGnv186/BCTxuEGAEVg0tabBOp8J@gcWrOh74nXC@7SUkzmCuRYCzdI1hx5BeXRp53kySiOaXYAM@gVF3az4Zj@ThxrLufdDEZ9SlGR@pC1xH3n3ppTbkw5kihAllpHxfOjq9DDcZQnjYoh/jphK@pMnrdrefSddAwQNSxJ06F9btvoU4iISl@u2oUVeoHfuEIk8BLceyomNjfpSlxgtdAjKR6acvhDcpjIXeAjKkDgZ0DaBqyCdu4huX1Y0Hx8z@MDfyEZ1Yj8ZMhA3qKdIqag@bf4Rv5NVH4TCMCEn@M9lydFnHLnBRtJ9h0k4QIGJIsf/FHNgG6V3Clz2FiEzfUVI@BkKU40wmolmeD73B2Sk2kF/2QLMnl6m2qGzu9wdiIJ6anlW4i0pC6lpC386UbF0kaxjCqmMhukmHuWGijpguPRQQDDaiJ2gm4XkGZazEXkwEfy75X1L@v6wxrWeaGR5/TMVHomlu5xOiMV5fJggY8ybZiZ7NS3KN@DsKNs7lRdRUGbFw96uuHBliTKW3gqb@iN@vVOlHlLdyVzpU7YjCVkjJSvM3qfU@ZjZTSD6/Qap0v@XpE9r7GM5X0frx9/LdlBARnPSluTBJd6vU73HS9aOgXZzAZqCsHFsb@J7XhQSh9MOZ3ADg7l/DRst4oRlOW8mnFozNhbm@9tT24y3qWTaLAX49TAmjFGDCpRnctEuDE5LEI9lDxvgCCYyGhCjdwtVXgiC08MsJhrXlXLXpBTAxyalhziRfSLvMc/arDHkVP5UrMT5xjzMTeevZvjBKJJd96eTab4bILuIvxRNuqJVSSqe5KEOHuSODSkwLrOgH2wWygGn9fzhDlRqJliiu46RVI6ypBX7PtYF2Lig/XP7JL1wYc99qAbjEUJjxk@eWFZMQf3URCOQoztRLFowpvBoItaR9rw3ZELtQwUsrKK6pYIorGye1YFLXs4v4tP0iEdCnniCCHfoYFIlBDetNvoTIYesP07nFpR4tIZeVapN2GBBoyZVyvsZh6Im5C1pnDab5tIcM/x6EFKhwO/EXgW7NFC2P1Y3NQWj28pT0e/EYweBkvahmX95abT@HXnA@pz3@Rzr/IGyW6lOjjnvXodOVgBkVTCSg62sav515Zl6IYbrBvOIEBX7ONC/xl4M7gNer3AKsGKQRlD2LSGwfA2aHqWdRxoJTDCRVZGzST6Yfdvhg0W7sCmywdmRC/h0GV1GHAY/uL6zOriBunKXAuVVpG2Gbr6ttNEAiqPk1YftcOksMAwAUwPLHQdjIAoS46Io0S6Z4kL7V2uURAF1MA4J4ZuQpOh1x91GtAzJMmyugCK1SBRZb1mAhOor9H10TnYm4UAusdEFFAIKFXSUzhYUmn@h3AQsmFKx@6rnsnC7NensQLDPRh2YPaNCEy9QsUM3KGDTz5WqqJ6tHfypXRcFvD86fjoc2W3vCu2z0jHjYpyimwrPh7tw@yitemsNT@CD3apCiVtSrBKh2ei/POn43K1Ko6OReXg034FoAH449LhSaVcdUXlcGf/dJe07wBBHB6diP3KQeUEsp0cuVSrKmZF5cTRnjgoH@98hNfSdmW/cnJGNe5VTg6xMtTql8Sn0vFJZed0v3QsPp0efzqqlgU2zNqtVHf2S5WD8q4H9UOdovy5fHgiqh9L@/uJhh59OSwfCzISMFq5XQYsS9twhMWaqJ27lePyzgk2KHraAeIBgvuuqH4q71TwofxzGZpTOj5zJdBq@S@nkAkSxW7poPQBGmeln6EK9MvO6XEZ4x8hJaqn29WTysnpSVl8ODraJVpXy8efKzvlakFY@0dVIthptewKvFmOqgYYQC1Ih@ft02qF6FY5PIE14/QT2js40MlfgDCAZQmK7hKB0QwCWwtEOjo@Q6hIB@oAV3z5WIbvx0hTolYJqYAWFTsnZjaoEIh4YjZTHJY/7Fc@lA93yph8hGC@VKplBzqsUsUMFTTIOAPWgUpPqdXYT4AXPwKzWopzXepOUdkTpd3PFcRc5gYOqFYktxDZdj5KmnsYDdcQonT6KDPwr03BSmv6022AwSWnJTKzZTQ6YtLO0W4ZVmQZrMqOEk5h1VlPhFIy02Cl0YnwGgtZ0wwub9r1Tq/VRx9TXYwFH9dh28UrWhy8qeLceuImDClfoQKpVL3@uVSHg261Xnfc7ykZQ@O5ElIM/lQuR7YRg@3jyRsFPxsbTPfNGKG2XkpFJxnqoQICczL1X7Lpm38dOCKbbQayGDrvI2AlOgpZbXKFqhSYGsnZEa/TiKokyQS9dyQ7UMG0Au816ignRctIytQP4U/vPnrhxcH4ALMzi7uyWTzEEhqd3wNVDVdCIRHoj4xI0GlRlV4YBL@20zmzOjzze@1@v5l2HFWG8o7gHNhOO88UvwzaieKZZHlCltTOMpJ@qM7dtIXR@mdJMiH7xRtSy9L4pz6iH0dhwzEfUGpKVZGwWgot0y@5OFokuUKGtkD3Cupk3PMdlH6ufMHTXG7ldSHx/aP@zmML7QUxCC0seDUqd0E/Hy84AwwwisUBJOnICBnZrFFG2ZvozHeQ8Qoz3XWaaPkDa/VVQOs6kAQ2sjd@16wTV@NhZ2xiD/Pwh@PSwfbp3h5MnYjt6/XVN2sFS4fd@tnl3zOshyLFUtSxAazjsE@jJGOU7MDGh0aKEUs7Yn9i4GwWM2KUddVp9BHjPGi7jbglE05k2NwQ75bpoYmeHSAdbEEBOOYtxa8zR6ZkgHSsqQ625tof0xbfh70S8YA0ZulOqNfG@Adh6@GvhrhukGQgyWIUOxc4F04XNO/Ze8pUlA43FLgHs3i24mMO46ZpQKIusp9F71p6k7xt9GLIpow4XqnbqSQgMZ/EQii7ih6P7E8UZ0QKgCl6GHz5WfIbPJ7JAHcU7s4PR6VRFci4p0uinDoSRstG1yTki60idNHLl7qmTYFSfkciRWNPipN1YBBjNBAqeHEI2vjGARd0HJFklWQB@37REd@YUzF4B8IpSI6V78C5s5ojoRRU/BD5rqJSCIalg5ww1e50HZbKcqbjWChyxsj0Q/Qg@H8iTWbA34QTJ0CPqGUEAfwuShJUphUcX4konTulaDC0GxE1zU9nEZgHs2OudMOk9mbM/jVAAtk7E/XhjMIettIzCIBMjoINc/xqk7QrH45O721HFkc9Sa9xPUgLuVaopWIKbmbtwqVtl6t0K/jiCIdlTUaF@1BUvOeD2yWNejgyJY7y4kVoMzhHxf/ILpEARA944tIrtlpNclZOjjI1D8hQS8aC09QRk2Bb@vCo1m5JGCEyY3O/1HwpQgHoLcRnup10/UdfsHluPOIircTihKLgYTxwPCbj4iND1l2SIWY3QDgvmiQMwRtCRne4QHQZOoXqi6CJ9AsyFMFKIqvDKM4gTreOB6SlZfVOY0@SSeRQjf1pjwPRByzVUjk8DvAhMTTd5T1x4E8A5e73NZtZLLtU7btou4iVsVhClsfbUBr9/hC2jj62G3B0OxPHE1@k0CHohTdDGb8Q1rPOUEok1KYfqsFtE5/eaZnhGPCEWtgZobdC0yP@oCZdB2ghyuFJxpk1kQbmVTy6pYSOnfFyXqQ3o5RNoAmFJSUiboo1cX/PuZigMmRoQBTshPpwQTabVA/qHfTwu@sPf8W1H7dAvWbQ1JFJDZAkC@ROqvQoxmNjxE0f9EOSaEBXoAREUyLPgjRtqApr9BvJTtKuyY6iY2LsUmrJH69HM6myloKKIsaVtQPzrWWgM5FKKzI0qA4Wml9ZJVRmHbgeHj2MUbTQuNpa2Oc9PaVs8Cai@EJtHfGJ5039dIZPUshffBHi6IEvqOOWW1BEGPesqFednucIP7Qp@NIJhk1TJgo7maY/QPEbHX36PeJFJTqUYf8a/igMJnACaGQ74yzBqKd/6l/16jv9rt/u9Ds@nNMwjPuYZzx8nNAjdlh72L8L6aIfSmgamZqT6Jnjy3AYNnzXesmCEZorHAWDtGmmMBpOSlccJoIk52gEGN0RSfw9SMZI02Ver0aFrLj/Kdnj5Z3Co2Vf5WcVZo0@ApAT3FbCgoJ9SEfkmGQ4nxamMlw@lcHA8VJkhO88YrEXw/gtkIjUMDGMFTJTZglmI/Bk9ijGtebYbVIMwiEGWgp2A7xyJkzTZ9fH23hhFnmHlgIbIr@eM4qyFmWMcQjxYfI4uVfe/MnYAwI/gH7@1SxumcUINMW1VLSlkM8rMsoo4ELmgR2ao2kmhlms04ZVqBsDWh8nocaTJ49Rgyx/YFMkw@xNcSWOyDQcfPDuuHQdppz6xMFFZVEsOhS3A7cgpVE69zjDBs/Zz9LgRyUuS85wYtqRkNMG0o@RqgFUwotHE@a1JsocU/n5EbOy8r29liBgcZbJmXHBbtpWOxfyQOnw@opqrf4QJmM7QT1p6rEYjvqDxe@k3qNzx8zIbLNo3XCcZw2BmdmKsFguNYm0xQk@TgpWEp8E08QpRpZmwEN4fKVnzeZJIo6LdRxvxfrkGTo8RrPIbkovKrq/mzz2cVG8RYtetdDoIUW4Y5DSgv5eq0PD64/PIBImH6/qNGPUccqoT/jRAJUgk6bS91OIuE/inqBHEyiH9TaBdmb/PErUpJGcCnmqkmJBLpGeGLgdnTZhXhq00PgCw8TxDldPUnrDOXYnpMrLZy4xyDAmMEDcFQeZSA7FEtyosxJ8RLcDtNJ1tBbK40wET1umhYMO@q8JRlH5pXBHWjzUJ5n8RYEhjTUkOFVQrqcgKX9zeK3VxwRlihQwxGeQQrdoam66@v5W/WhbIB9A4NKULC19cy42xhHLgA38MZPqY9wDR1XJkrERFR8IdZoaYCzAKaXdDfi4iru/zpA5Hq0b5DCCAwR/TuPPsiyB4bzXcpraWGTcnGAWR5KbR5sjMltcJGIofkfyy6HIW106uAKAgDGG8sU8QMCwpoQ9KgUo9I7JeTFEZR9BwWIehyV8pKiokZ3njHQkqszwetXIkZuV460JIzMTCGwsZueJEIE9y@wsERRY6GbiYuR4M7s9UQ7YECveZ4pDV8heidNQ9xwTkC4izjnRjFLLCzcnOZgSX686sUTN35T6Nmek5pKpQB@NYS2TT6au52KpsWpXVuJFYyWBHo5ZaywRSOGYCOtZ4cf@kWuKGfJc24Qah4zYLkPaZ/fwKHWH5zbvr6HYJKdstcdQ8EzPcHX8qvMVK7Gg7E8HYBeLpDLA2O0/3FplmaowkXcFUFw65eyS5gMh7VhtXOqxWXjSVZH2dIACdabtt8Tnk729WNjXy4kyNLoOhqu5XA6Z@NIMfq9sq1GU1Oln47mzrZtuNzu4@2n4@TJLc38Q0JUAG@oEHUCXwKAIvf6wzTdDIA6QFXNnpCMrnvVvWi3zCgbUUGLnQbdxThkNQdAC1NFGL59PSABEIOUC@ws2ENv3i9Cj787njaaEotRQUBpNgm9tpT0D8uCHFtpna00VAcOJWVkzwbrlFLe@4QqCN5tQZ1H4YudbZJ5sfwy63b4rvuBVwRgpYO4hWWBvzyyQ4yyoYSTv3puQ4tG6IrjtdA2/Ysxi8jqCUwuTumdCxYXH2PjHQbs8HqTt2lcblhVo8jI2cxnjU7vCbtuODBb/HWCZDwHt78p97Q/SDaJTMjMs9XIER0@A0au8O/PsE8vikExM0uz53EjU2eh6FKwBmu7QXkDFsqfupZY8kl0T1z4f51tIwxzDkDhhzJXvK4GuZn/etHg7arW@b1akawC4Y//QjMg3ofzYhEg6ABqBcvgBPTGK9r9kYFjvJQKK8AYHL@uYnnewQB0LWNaLRvG3u3SpVBILg@VlUSptw0MmI0rbJbGLH7a3xS68b@P7y@LK6mqB59xd5xt83FYfH8Q2wCAJ53LjargLr5BWRL8xtNbGLl7IFhfcwkK9uLlVCLO10ja69cPTP/7tP/7x7/@ZLcmX/8aXbXqpfdWZPM/LLjS@Lbx8KOB7bfdiceGytjC4WGwXkMv@SVHD@5VRxo/MR73hpZXiVcD4Snak6pxN0WdkUaFu9bv2h7/C7LIhUo0wm5JfQ745iubYVCMwvgfoR3kJR3h16UDyKA9IpADoBMXx0DuNAA3wYL0BSgIuaAfK5Vm3ogT3GA5GZ9BalZSMxEN71tsAfVqiSAroiwsrVqbTC4MeSsBvac/LzbMsH347o7rk3@zXg7C93R@LpfO0WMqJJVcs2Tb95NfewldnIdtB71zOBscB23YhJVItoJmhCDu00aPzA921kyC3ZS3QlT0ISYWpoMzsBefq0x85y/CFa2HbmsNLMwWLSEjJhEVS3xZ6D9At3yDHgx1ztaGNQl2eYqgyQ6Oi@xe3QH7IhgBRzddMkI0@VImaPvJIxqes@iL72qLbhAgwkvX4wx6Ne/wAa9FCT9o8x85SeM0Rmc/zV1wbC@wMTWhjCtcfIUAKFT5O5siTcDG1aLGVt9FKaiZ7YZvtk8zHtg6TYKRs07nQvwqDCdia2yTcQk/6tUhDblavCLuj1StGVXbS9ltYRpHrm@6oM5DuClQ7DqhvurYHHknYowSI4XDM/o3pEUaCAhUpKtEtfFnWRDT72HQeCT3pmg4d7HisOTKIkP2ahrF9nxjbTpa8RBQ7MA8QUtqUr@V3uqGMujIkYrf94SXeDui36EK1EevNSJ6H16QmMO63NNIeQSaT82g8Q1NSg6HfvvZdkTrsnwz9SQWWLdj5jBqeAy3EEEyIBA4@WfWs5imEuUWyS4giuilkOYSXF3Qn8no07ltb@5xgl6qhIMOu4CCIsRNRMriP9VWCjhFX/4FOMFGemry1NlJOsTTzoqWRhGSbbjM0zKaGjqVqMMeOHji2xajqkal4QRa6wYX2mhS/MJN3MUaArNuWXoDSFWHtLdaPq1M76PmxxWnQtZSjf7YgeF3E8UxXUbI1kqVuPs1HN94hVrCP/BqPAsFrkwpnZM2l03PnobzOLWWuIxTkW9viZ33R0RfQ0QVm5BkiTnsdniwTK1R0B4YnKmT5DxBaXb8N@E3u/Amy4nkq/W4@69S@nvcultLnvfvz3x3CRE7JapXNiJRUZqsZS44VWBmzbuxVWaWFKtTgeS@e4bwn2IfFIAEgkk3XvmYv7rOA0HkK75Q/TzFBYl2GmGSfri@L4LNTaKbiWGRT1pyz5KjOT7/LOwLWVvrFPuQPDv8CFupQSWJ6OOcMWwCK/HR/u2GXkzC7vpJ7vZJ/DSehdjDODIMbXG8z4c1lMIatRIjHWVh6zn@PcUOMEA/j0C/AxzG0k681Yd@TUDopySlUDnOqx9JsBWU85gnID1SmcKno4uLoPD4qH/HA7wpgOZWXYkGx6aDBfWlcP8P@NdbjhzivJb1DmCPRyoBtREiEmkHI6vKVxzjUUcNlkfycPLGDsVsJCHRvNmWsFr1@LyM3a463WMBNNHrNdNdz67nkGJ0aorERuiA3U4vzIr/17s3f/@vot9QotbWS/TKE31Hqt9Taeoof4QHeXqm329RWahOzrT2kJlk4A8Pjm7//D5Tf@gngYMpkE/5srSpYa5PUVqZIRe5TW2vwkF9ZgXr/929/gzYs8IkN72JdqLuCECsoiuz4PeJdSBcVbCUfSxejaYUcsxAGWxjC2Rxe0DBqvLKeIzFdSlpV3AYy8pWyR5FLPBlmjchUiCUZyp4CdkZcoIgVZBikMqFoCcN2Q5ltIPNGaIpfXnhrIZwAfpHmHLpKbbrxIkSToQU@FkEHprlGOM/zw1buna3NOzZsZVNSUFtIPNrJuXb9VeH/AA)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/bix2f)

IE5 is separated from IE4 with `document.dir` (see [prop diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/drnu7)).

Answer (score 2):

## 319. [Tetr4phobi4](https://github.com/NELMVN/Tetr4phobi4), 14640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[250=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26 ^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy\#184  O@     <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#111#y#y#y#_#          ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo  a;net R[+++].----._     /112\    ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"*1220*1220L *1211 >"  082",,,@_ 2 2-----x########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1   v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>> @ 0:8:8/_ }\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S 1111>>>> \)      # ##########>>###>## #####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>##### ## # ##  ## ####
#comment -[v]  >>>>>>>>    xxxxxxxxxxxx    [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_ 9 h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>      #v                    @.7.8.2<
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$]   )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]  ( '4o'6o@ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMnMnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM              @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#   
#<<<#
#>--><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99>ss<!--
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d111 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n110mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l11110000011100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||110')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  #e:>* * * * *[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]* * * * *<
♈  
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
X#  
x+------+XX   X       XXX
x|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
x|/0011 | X X   XXXXXXX
x|/0010 | X
x|/0011 | 
x|/0001 | 
x|/$0011|  
x+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+>
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!s
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa










































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?311:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::gek:>Ex Cr Uithar5"3.c"F ._#a gi[s]pogr3461  prstd6,1 8,8R ,0,1ute_[2]!!\0/a4on; $/op>s'0}e}equ+4[0]tfc;[ ]5:ore在ｕ  
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,11]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1, (0`id` ),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>         :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\              \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js "(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ5L3U7W62SPbtK4G46AJQAKoJVKGrABJoNjskza7WGntnPRrZIcszvrJmPSuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzmZVSiQANgtjyM2NrZIVOXz5MmTJ0@efLcMr//zn0fwYU@dwaw3cMZsbHpj1nGtC9NV2YMZu29YXk7PSBKG2nV7k6Fpj72yFGEaY97YcMdsYNi9idEzWQRcdTa3d63B2HSTzDNN1jIHziX4ZxizzUt2aLetDkBiY@fctK3Xpgt@WcYemoM3wzdj1naGQ8PueGzkWvaYfHOMPTXA0p20z5nR8sau0R5bjg1eecae2QNj2OoYjIKPXJNHKjAA1T6nOIs@RcYeO65nQgpO2/Q8Bx1L4Gi4lvNo98nHN8JrafaxAUiNBub0RvKaxp5bptu5GUNnn50eHNx0zbBPFcdmB7dR0rJsdzJ2Dsc34efYbs@0DaarJVW/6ZkHYo7NQTFdTC94gd@B5UJpGqLUyvOSsSfDlukC8UURXlrjvgoRTh1OcObYgxkzpwAMcOxCMHPMLCwtlkunMST8n5htx@7MwYOTCXAArjkcjWdMYbYjeAC8HJd5I6NtKh1zYA2tsdlhAwuwc7oCG49BgbNzc3bpuFDwCmdFQsQbmW2ra2EUkQNPQmZ7aLYmPeZMxqMJoOexjuUZrQEEa81Yx@wak8E4yVrgB8Qj98u@aQuULLuH@Xg@d0EINlQBjv2mBrSxBgMG6JwjOpi0x7bR4xLdMWjLJCzNDoLan5MLIBkDz8/9YsILyWC8p67Tc40hMGrHJBp8dviUeW3HBRv8MCyvBevAtI0x295m0f0nD6OsFpBRdVtSQNIqu2KMRXxPdmEMJqbHhsYM0rbHULmYQ@Xnx5AgOItuRMssmskwPc2yWZaFylZkei7NoEqUwAC1Vs9o8MszvciyGvB9LprEdLqu0bMGJofScwZdBFRAjtVzTId3OssyWjGa5CHalE6BZYosX2CFHCvAu8RKOiSEULNMK@Xgl4cfQCkBFhr8MlmeWsAayFKQDbbHusbQGsw49NEIwbdZTmMFgAioagBZLwKEko4QFp8wvHEfiNs3LgCkMrDOUWSYgdTAEkvBJ7W1lSKxhfKRJ@n1zcEAUwViAZlyRVaAVPOQ8SykDLTUi7qf@V6fsk94FdLwAxwLkOMikDgN1EojuQrwAzuIIh1kjg4CRgeZoWvgroM5g1AhXB788lBe@awPXe8QbUHCQlwNiYlCRUMaQDQoBJaBosizLBRxBos4l2GAJyBQyDOQK0WNFbOsWGBArlKaAek1QAbLXwN5pgESGgKDYtWgXDVARAOG0QColskxKURXLYP@EDcDcYEEWhbiZMEM5aLl8QfxoOA1SFKDNHW9NGcvwE3PQSZzGeI7PQ@FVwA/IJYOuOrALTpgqxfBH@MWgXBFZMuCTwhjMOobSAsoAWRmYDUgSA5wItgQHsx6IcNZikK3zLHVlq4lqFm8FQxLHV@CoBQAicIMho0oMOCce2KBFIyDUFoUWBPPHAAXgRxpG2BGtoUaj9LDh2ONVZS10FSZzgU2piQCFpLxSEy0XGxJQWZ1TNdlGBYaXC9JAsWbtDzz1QTb2zleXZBQJgjXrmENAgSo6hhjagvgG/Ugvdki2l3XGVL9GqLAGDjOaIXoBfF0iYA@cS7NOepz6WWMRgOQ6eBuAiEmxgCQuTRIJyCVIZwqRwgiYbx23wKAlBTIVss120R7kXWInQEpvIhimem1exmE8iDUNGTYyAHB6mEcezIYlKHJM9ssU0t1zIsUuvDmY7HZQBz8BgXaRAGiZUB7Tg0qYhFAuqer1FSd@iXrOcPFrHHxchhkvW9hMzC4NGZQel2QLObUGILWwbBpt6HxHgLH8BLEkvB443PIOo4dHQdQLl1oYiHTQU4A5IBoMraGJuhkDkTBEs8S0ijcCLPWDFiZqJVVSSXjmNwglCrdJBR3yIYceGWBxq0zaSPVMG3LJg6CRsGjFqsGcLniqaIBqpxrGh0eDDUMxCikI0GLZwLRhTrQJkCopZi2BxqPpzILVUNg@J7TBR6jZhrUDYg6T6dNececB05Tta1KRGnkm@H5gFmsPRoxcAcdBdA6SBehnXVeWuw1eA76Hhu0J647Y9MRFIA1hFDjttPtAtO@Nkd9AMGGHdaetaFWQi6RaaSOQxKoPbqR5cC2aUIY24Rs7z39OuuZQG1olbuAKXH6PAOjEWWBSGHYvMW2DaAUZqE9mhFZAEwQo@s4Krp3HNMjHgGNJqjxmJhn9qhGQPXqzmXQEDUQYE7QCmxgWRA4olYhfExQWpoZTEoU/semDTWmDcwIdR2KD3XSXdYF/T/UWKOCZ7Tb5mgs2MMhKWbZIaXm6ACVGnJVBDDV60ub90EfW8BAgqCSzzmhFtw4J@GKyj7pWgaKWNHJgDbdNgM1lnGBMpjdSh5CXNxIXX6BYRYweCGvwGFENQE1PJINkzFKEBSKVruPInCMQoa0DKhk7uR29sEtnLw7ZEo3SBux0UDaSGoqcEI8VsNQ4De4DUgdDRBWbcEBgy443AHa8IZLIDsBkoNO2FVNGSrIwruADh3bWQIViBnAxSCLPlQWxIwnKDWMQcCMVF28hTJCOT3v/2L7BU3naOS4UDO40JmhJONFFuIuh/dVYkETEYe@82KLCi1FFNv58Zj3u0YD6AtRFcOaCvqkAZIChBjvBYDMc3iKIYSp1hMsgd8lSXzOTNCE2raJKqnhzjgQyB60ypDQjFmuC2LwAtsG3vT4bYhKfApNgdHpoGRFclC9v5m4ihy9N2lZ05tdjTY6qi896cJwWRd7GS7oGlCJYtGuF41XyJ1ihrzklDMapygqf8sQkAKpUOSxLnRcoCE4AEFzMrPbMXmhislJJk/G3aIcBwNG5KoZ@6oxGt/E7iW4IdMMz6Fek63CetBqKwq8FXQjTNAjpaKH4YJ6AZUQtOxSqdMy2BuQHi5TpnsUG9VC@mpqNkjLtDtBWoIQiEs4vypPwnPbZFBCrRrmAINTzqmRWCDge1KCIsrgkEqJ9hMdSMnjfqTOcMeJTUMELMY1kDi7ClR0aABihIwFOofVtsZNoaXcu@frKxvVKjAbKFEgNjvxsHLvj6WoIKkhsEpKiEhEHTsnY6wbsTjkFwNfc2xAWwJOrdbY1bjvQo0j@7UEgYCsko2c7BNWlPMT63zSuVnQNjpiIBlrHehKVnssVyRo/HltqK6janSBqqD8R5GqyLwYn0DfYl5yxQKVRTDX9FDrrQpUQiUcQwwEry4lEY8q3OYMvTdrD4RKwE1Q2bk0agH656K3HgiipNAJ/Ep7q6ZyIFgdOBz2dPf0k6qoi9wz1bLs8oLDwGkbA3LexOCyH/fR4YPj3eOvN5fAGFit8k2HlJUt5rGpnUyVnj1JZVW9vBmGMQf8sLkeNkZcDCNLwpspzjSkKs3a0LhMfXIeHX96kySgCSE5KAUw4@@GSsPDgNIltQyvf6MRZr1EApIMovhhmXLIfJiBAVFHf8PH5@nk9WssvJtIjYQ7YjaYGByA75g6tP14KnreUMB8r1aXt4gUF7RQy8Yx0LkpHNLH52PUmm8iQ6p0iGU@PjrYP64S2L7hnZuDgUJBUt4YdCnD7ajA84NJx5SWhQHxB6Y2S6hzxFGfJlyXErjdXiDwvGzZCvgAALs4qsOUwdDPmtcH3Pdu5o1clXbAAWQnCDf1yrA@1P5QREN4YBPXxp7uslaUPOaNVeC0tMUKfBebrXYuZxaypXCz1Z6n2QkDHZJSbDm@3uiC17mnoIs61yKFWi3QP3l0C3GPlEjoCig@Zt6AqZSWN5Cw96JYLOql9qCH5gxM9TlJPJnJ8VQq6g9@qm2P@pyh8PtTaxxLx/lXi0NYSH1391B/6AcWA3U0gEGdBuyCY8vkdnGyoe0Bj9jOwOk5bAvicO3QTxDUppXZ3O059q0SMtARsxrB2QuQvzheY4ygrbFeU8eRYoW7q3zmw7C9S5DSWj6DRCIKEagUhVdfGhcGkGue75PDb@xDI6Ll0unAnKYHSBCKQ@RCUzvkSg5MgYRUgc/SDAYzGbdqu@@hhKYSMNNC0AURd@feSx1JYqqppeGXovRV5xbFXzqzG6wFLpy1wBAi2eGTp48On@w/3v38bKzncgv2bLqUB8JBei3QhdQ@pxvW1i1eNTFbCC4CdcPF6gVSYAIdFH9IfOK5ILhVDKJyBFZwDZ8Din3V6dtRL34zM5foq7y025yFHmPl40FFROhodwbYGXH51Bm258g//fF45JVTKajl/UlLhU5r6mXbGRi9FMWDhmEwSGnYdTk8wnENb1kMQMabmTwGH9MC1WFGA4fGYOhA54Wm41A0sBgHT4NVA6vXh74wztmZblwNOJhyk@pADwH6yqkgbySAyQa0FV@/nGTO2l/R9CLnay2tZ1OyH2yh@kPYja4JXacYtFZAivgNKzu7d3aPzUBKI6SbQCJM3RLTNtgWDBgokjRYiv18nzgkLXCYFGUF0ejVBAdxQUqlculsQcvnUtAtg24a6KwKDrUpQ2Pc7itjRwF4itOlcYMQF3a9tmF31S1h8JEFve8jyGqm/sXZmd0ABf3sHuGGk2H1WaOuNeIVdjvKlggfrwD3LmQPedd3AN4lI7AmfdkKedYxbouzjkG1q8NS4@FItDnKiD3eBUXqtQPyumOG6x5GSIU9U1sLYVMY@G1qyYDQAKNK@EJKpaBCQUsLrJdCvBRQelE9BM4BuRWKwOajGTwffAo6JEew0418bzlRj8bqUa/BQVJvBESkMeY2SmkPxwfH0DoGnI9SGgoXhTS7NKM4fG54fJASIomJRz8@9NUCCDQYHwxE28GEKzABxaLuOUgO4CscLe3PRxmx0w@cBgkSTjj4ABqETZMGPZAzEJlnZJdnhKdELotZOredSxuhtUxWVFrWmI/xOxMXJ/SsTjhvEDyj8zAAjTIXkus089cy23yUlUemXEAn0GBDc@jgUAJoVyQKTMqCwWcNsS/o4UA1VKu0ghMnAF9h9/dAirVNPl6kDLETBSy1z6JjN7WrfCNlKK@Bm9foVpj53fAkNhX6qU8AGokMZrFplESMgJJ24gwp0HMab0HPB766K41m4z7kGDhMNqrOyLRv9vl4jzAWr9BcazQKAt@yY1fRjY2NaDlaiybBtAOmbTTtoCkBph0yKWTCcCqaKEaSTOhbpxjo1ohe133I03gDeWCKmsNraxQz6uVyppE06pr46viNQ1EA5SG0gh@AE41Xq2iMx@XaJU7VgP4eyvse8s5J27VGggRfBYWA2wUNMkQE6N6jNu@aFeybrqfIsOpCp9FEFTPmRs/q6bPG2dVZJ3F2HU1i7HjFqEL/EITXODZUe64zGYHiVs@WFZBt8Xqm3Ki0qtF0dCsWKyoDSMiIxz8qxhMGp3UsagJPxc7OokBSQZ16u@8SvGlSj8cDQgEeXQt6GYNBLKpeFSH9VrwRT0QhbjyaBLFcjUaBLm0kgkeZxhEBzkQH1hRICRUTmrjwnAIJSJqTwur6DXPUn7nhAMGoG2jZOII@n5CHykBSPCwlX/P4YYVuoafv6708HCi3OHiH@tJoxqW7xDE9Sy0sDvHb3QulO3TGRuozFTpNaqi5jG5EU4oCLSH5cEiU7ceWh1XYsE1n4oVHGpcOgGLq4Hran4Cw9FfOJIGrrJFktvsOi27eB@gsmObBpgRnrBQ@7@UD6LRV@KEQRa0EJ0tAu6AlJRbIRVxuwkdlNEKCix5/bD6XH71Sg9QqFIelMSGrZzuuqQBJIIZEC0BouZBUY2JVySGNfN2alxC@1KRhx9syQSIeDByDaMvFdWg@aDQMxYf@OUQ5NjvSAORHF8SjysvCNTupLYkmZx23Dy0E5AYlsR6U1lB4pBxv1FHHU4gqxbDBDXvy3h0onZeso@t6vp3rln0/5Aogdh8KCXulNnRxfS9FA8@4KOR9Pizk99GfHD3c52Mn1Nhi84rjaM2h05mAXin6Tcem3UuyfeAny3aGFpDBj//6fHDsOGPeywfLqpEZ3mm2hpOBQWM@N4dl1sZrOy1nQENB66LOw09czxgYfBDK99397DHo@s9OT6pqORQoZVwM16aN45DLk@X0PAzPOdI0qz895HHGlDdzMrZb/oI0FDPCI48eE7EcDcrIdy@gu1@lcA5FuBfRfYhL0UBXFqMIZA0cRcASBcTlabiqRzheaelrdF/ZBwvCaRSOK45zbK80ndwvxt3ugnOGnM8VFE2DuXOWnPkytYU@YhilHA@Ea9YWwoQB5SlMsHTtZjghvIIlBn1z4M8gHoNigrNk0LYPUH2Cvglq4nz9mAmK9AgnQ0hC4xQba4Ou6d0atoA6NVJ4aCmyQfUE2rAUai7SZoqJIe4K1RTbEVOTHpeeDnTtafRku8YnrLHr5PJeW4oPvm82AcR2reKvJloVDFOKRoNgBJVwgxiUTZq2v5XVYBGGR2PqEkWpSF4Keg1TPa2cTQv7jZRHROgy@exs@lFa/xw6H7jua/NeqmdWMLmV1CI7H4du90FssMR0kWRQDhO76ww6Cp/0gvJnvLuEBSGWGgQrz0jgg4vl@ovOLFzEIhYHgrgMrVe7BfdG0dVuBwitcAsAQW24Ym/OkxdvWB1asAvVGw2scYNdq2On2cfMjyeufXMtHFcpXdeYeZJYqVJlu8cff1ZPNzgEaWjgRFaRl9bUX0oJejDoPbhiFUy43mZsjalhp4UFFuZXUwGpKc15APoAgydQYUFCIkeI@hvzzTwvXRM6njETMfdmwyQz49dqd2CMx6bNeYvPJq4mN5/2EclUKfkdMYdQZmmaaAFF00I/QLHCTk4f7h8fq8ChXiy6jxMyZah2RrsP@saqTPuUDGe@zD7qRNlHGCeOvXAJqhR0JpoiPjBvBZgbuhOQOoqCnunGwDGOcyltcKbpK4rIFS5BIFw11R4TjQJgMTMOeSJg5aX4P7N5z0ngWWZRliBKArlj98pAWyuuTmzrlepBu0FqKASJ8r4nLZOtbsZIfG1qceIf1xriXDB0mUgLhDzU62wDpBuFlln1LfuinlZKjcQmazQqfIYfIqJOT8tuxRJOQ9CTT4eRgBQ4H4peWffGQl4/BRq5xVgcPw14VhJ8C8i6k9bsdi2VN3U5HiCrvAYH7infRHLJQlOOor@0iUQIrYRaXNG0uF4qlK1n1Mm@sUAcsuMjEOQHpyFjPJdso8q0eNzHjAN6brjYdS6zp47nWa0BrWDtDiy@EixorMuCMAKST5lwchWsGEQ3rM9Qz7Aw5suW@WJgQQnyp4YGelKYM3KIxdkVEpNIqSMV2Zs36CCzTZ0RG8i4apjT99rv04J8fOQAso/EKuiwzkFCQyxPQdFxJsl@521x/hd9eMcgdXFD51Uu5HA8rnNa9rlDs0iBqZlWtRzqmUHs4fngdsyu5fXptRA0wIGH1Vdh5w1bXXotCUCTKWKanhxomF5o2FCcRuqYPjRivyTlxaUpC8m2zO7E7tGcJpqZ8uqOkEqpSIG7rZa1KigQAVeb@d8lwUBWYs3T1ayq@bUHB3igWQT5yftE86zfXNXEFugOjdQYYonvf/5mB@h/u3T60F7heGZgaIKmgCWldFcWloiKFnotL1g@7D4ZWAYRhkx3gWwbLmTJGASG5aBpal9RQN8Y4kSFKHHgTXyBLrqGzTjmfJ7R/y5PZNlUnQ1yu70q7I1VXjwpmlSC7mKHiMB1LsukSCRkeSGYUz6xE@q4o8C9Gyl/KRYjZubl3p@MJ/wN6vCdhWiN8LeuboqQ6ZzR0kzokBoty1xT5K5xPuk4yui8F6jF@SVh57mnmWUFtBIxydxE4/Ls8wy6Vg@ae/@7Kti8fU1d0ucurvDsiTdSWtS373AbVYThmhTcAX@vCmKJ3UqBYTXVrAG93pMTBXRgFLHGIoUrWJUQ0awbZB4YrRmqQv0P57JgvQJInGo7kUhnVkxYj0ar42P/lOKXSstjT9U2p8eykYcUXyWr8LE5yrBYN3tHqUJzZQ2NgaJ3QsaVwnzZcodbQYOZUopjXuA80cXSkptTHxuk9mRguHPTGhaf4@FPTqwa5xbNhqjLbWdgeVihB6ukpr/mbp4WrlOmV2hdhbWMkh3oiGI7rgSm5VLAaY9xLeoKtnoPmcbXgOJK2xCfqM4qYrWdS/yt1CD60Bnm7@WN2uulWL2HfFIG7YEBTfnKFmFh1BFHNe/g1UvLM@m1nLDnSxEdtwdL3RdrgT@eGB4fvIuzPWvgeOyE3usI1HOBCvy9nKfDtLQMW6FR9rB5jRjyF0/MC9QY9JxBvthLGfBaWeoTt4uiX3zfV8gFQkrT7hBSvgbk2Jr4rhTt5yn3/K4Cov1fLi6cDRnXtLLLJJWY1FmdO@gb4Izg8pwdpIsUU03xMcQVCeNczqUx87@/QOuxirR@6zGakUYNCh5GKBXBMHa5lv2LpJZdn1rn/YTSLbCFuzIRKtzzgQntFb1vFSnT09oHxtDS6fcXUd3BxJyYS/saR62XJm4lXtPPeH@k0iIbm2IKAGcdcM9LEOq16By@F9bYVKNtrTAxoNdu3q3NLAq1ESjgI@w9PwXDUzTcjtGzJ6OFUl3ooNnH60nWH/lV2uksYIc@HyqHincoSwsqumfSb22niXfycOVZNZtOp4UOE5rKWbCs60xlgrgvLf5eSJhc5inPw@L0nRsyLk@DyBJe27hSBOmr@vYUuFRK2ZZtjmf4fk9p2nKcwYeUFAjVjoXaGCiXtIZ3XYndUnfE7hQ2H73wcMyj1V01bsFbG9G9BPpgv3ldoYfnmt6rNBWcTR3iTNeidf0ITmjm6q5UcEs3DgvxVb2D1bqkGBDR1KJaWFvruIbqtMyBwT/TfHYdvJKaWQtvUWiIWWCcNeZzxfM5/sgNoTSaAbGsDnRU@ubQJOsaRd/ovJx4/mdloKmDv1XeU9Nsp6b7ZntVgJEFcsHG98LkdEhZGjs2dLHGuIAQuyoDXKIqXFdJYH86cSmRD4dGz@TnVKyTlPMxC1ymw3t2c@Py0YsyX5rThmjzEebVLAGV6tycef53KcDHszaU62R494jbjcrfxmHQ96jtq9bG3m5i7b7Tt/tmny9ID2yrKgfw45ifK7IOdcC618c1cqPRwtr5MD0HzmDwPvRE0cgFpeN0l@K0j7tqcUvYB8GdGS3wEJ87x@@MMZcdaFhZa/rmBNolzxk7I1Mh26qgAxzr4e9VMtSf/f5FB5HWdvWBIv73F4V/Z9@yZzjj0Yg@zdFg4tGLoiq0GfouvanL17zQakvH7amvnWFLFY6qWBBDk@7LRUzLGrf7uAmdc7bZc1rtvnUX0i3TGNvWecof9eHW9@q7ImUspjxEZ3VgAXndmYr8Ug37n@DncFWhiwEk3qwFhjX6yrJBOtrvrYyM87bHB0TRxMo4JhyqjXxXeJm205dfTazxHGhokVQwwstnJtCwCnexLGOlZkWbL@ZiWCzXWMmlpKSjQq6YaVB4tJXjSwsL6EJVLJPhr1UIhXNJGIUWvHwIucWiIhogtEJDt@C@wF8Lq6GWNnJ2f9LzbgtMPmLfARUNX6uHLWiRdGjUGtoswxafVWTWByncPQnfJuhcE3PttEpu7bwKhdMGiuFY8GnCB4pusnIMbWCNPP5mSnflbJxYJAV98ZtThpw2s@WdaVEwHbPLZ0HQdJeKOHRonhZ0EKWNc/o4iI7CnCteXHDZTg@EujJg88B@2FVqy9L1R8uLP2gzlc@fmD0DF3E/ssa4CnQJVxDLLlu3dCfsr00Mz/raBHK2itnwKAg@E@mGzwxA2xJ4j42e1f5koSACJAWBxRJS/llgf3S6XRaXfcvDNVSBYc3AFLIcZ2Lkuib0G5aEvDl0H5yCMa9AfH/l0tDLhted0Qy3oc3ItG5k3RrTKKv4ruo6rlpdthaJy8lwNPHEZzkOtEorPAo9PCd379IC4MorEK2sbwzGy0eqQ0OuoIWJRnFuXKWNf8MaOD32jWKagdIGShgq50sY5wE0z09xaZBrL@FESvs9Zz5xoENxecZeQdmaGaZYtjVeP5ozHuMyIf@LmeEtB259SD3Ct3r/QyEop8sp8uhuXX@@5/mO9h0478SZuG0TjcFBJuFugUjV3POXNeNWEQcPYrkM99LWzt5Ac@jYk7HiTuy1rUJ@batQZtNiPsQGLPa1/cfP4mFuoGXgd2mhJnT@Jt5gNjetXDNwg8ksGxSx1XJ0MbTfl3jIz106pjXId8TZxcOh2iSuHzrL@jtPZ645fu8OEwj/yfCh2caZwzvTfuI8dmwHWqMRCMrhsckPE1hY67E8IkZ7hNvlgT6dO5M5IbArGiGubRgjswXlO5ib3qct4oAfGmNjRVNEY4PU/wtMd/KKNWiZ7ksa9AuZV3VpFxH6xJxS32I1w/A6qIzbba4S43jcQh1ZmLHxRo5j8zdJ2zR8tMfrpQo0BfR6/7lyFVf4L4wLLO2fLWb16IIvFDE7/LSLVXl1zZYz4O81y5Jsiy8LMFzL9FKP8PAEcstnmQLal7dWhhTWypB51wg02QvDo3n65V2NOUht@gGrgPqG23ZwJkwY1izQCZ14cIeYDjYN8LUDLSD8FCSW0Z6IsxfvQmswbA3ptbLDECrNY7OF241adEzI2JjeLkw@MiTOSAgt6gpOFvDFFVbqPIs9hd5I/O5ma6EftUhVa0QvktQrp8tpvY5iW2b7tYGjZg7Raz42veAPeU49IeOKsepQNaJR5JRBW@iX1qTF1Wug0AxMZdx3oc@fGq8b3vbPb1kyHzIZmjjJvDgLs1J1dbw@ZdZZPp8eCFfXVMTZgSBLgnMEuX6o7K7UPBE8/B89@GoKGuFmPuufaQKi6@4ZfEB@4tri8z4c@NTxxl1regR4476DVeIEs5WDKPDhNQNNW6syAaVnTwZ89KEXWno17FB3TKEzbBVlQOJ6bCqmfaHQCXPT2zly@G6y1C4ehjo2O4o4YAFnGpRH/sayIJj4LplADctGXO@ppThhp/msWAG6jLiXvmQAfcsZKyOPvqmR9/Tw0dGpOvK0pe3Tbh/3Y9zS4xZObNCL6dCQ1EvDDc138hVpHcsbpx6caMreo0MVA6ygN5/RUOCDM3MLn5XjnuLoUSNlrOwFoa85Xq4gfnL6@FFivveTxfb6rjM042HvvZOTJO5t@erJUu9w7AOoHV1nujL64b6mxZew7zObZgdXSc8lKa2CdGpCbxSY8RN@4MudylXbGZmd09nI/AwaT5Tg3nsmn1@ZySfGhdXDWshKKwlFFZWV1Hw2HlqcDZ1t0w2@q8rz3BqhtGzTJ8U/K5ejoOaQSbmZ5drDuhn/m1oMS4uVCB8WSUvf5taxpUDN6PXRlDK8vy9imqatovOJ0YVyZbmVhbUYYNn88MC5eI@pZFN0XpTASRkDVynWnUvJC8oQRHcKXzg8LxzB2Fq5DGYdgMA5v7TCX5r2zLAVmstap16UITYualsb5Bvme0xIBSt8LvBA6KVzfMGqehZrkzF@R8KnbijK3t6Dw7siHAtarg/18ZNn7Knh4ekm6wOGMTbfA@O5ZvRSwXErPFpv5XRqxwVQ@lp4vdHy@lxmJ4bbcezZ9O5JONrcik07HVYcwEIbBTIH1tRa1la1@bjW0@XLjO5Km@/jcGYLenD41BsB6N13/pmmpdN0phF@tTS33lEyfgVnMTQZMzwoL@x1ehiIhjbqLSo4xJf2Rh@ZU1yOwkeDl3Xql7Zv@TVtXyG@ujlZ51dc45ddk94tP3RkGTWtrQGYW@PHcmrg/cgZXPYddc9wTe89yySE2rosldZkqRSS06@LaRwOpSlGYV6t7OM@BvFZyren5tjNjvpOy8quyw3flHU8scPHBHtJcdAD30vJd7d5qn@WcyxmJxLx@OJ1AeG9fHwXGx4mxzegQdg3b9iG2GcGHsHWO7G7Dc@cAqXXxD2hEoHATYcxu1rVciW2g4f2l6FJi1OK6EQn@/hp1dnmldg0Vi5r17hxTi7LTGzqCw7q5IdNAlw8Jg/yxJRzjW2OwWfT33LG6Lh09oaRmgztspZLg01NhfcAV8RePEBp8@rp4dP9k9Pd02cn9XTjWo6LHaccN9uG1Py9yB9lOjLkXZANqh8/epb2rA4gOTrKHdVrz88Xg5zdyFp1IWvzTMk7GGfzyrZTKdp6mVKuAT9F5qmRL7Sl6MRh@zmm8hE7Z8t8x@KASCpvctAypQllVmbpZQmPDM@DbAn/m5dJkC/LZNCXJyxOCwWW7DlOR6Tomezux0/xYPfw0bPjfeYjOGeaS6sz7ldLOX6YLDZRignl1LVoFUeVRUWUKJRVtRo9iAJhomqUlWnDKx3kCnwOwXzq4FZZEXuLxTYJPlAwGhRK6j9/M3UdVXFBYhzCRn2kokxQHgOwU9zE9mc/6fCDzv2jK/xbU9whyWM6IkASG1RXbE9FilLFHK2@O4UOFqedqMGJ5vP7aCQ65x648pJOnbpxIlGcDgnhF@GIA6P8hIhB/MORcWQLD3@CbvmFhdtQOQ5dPItpkZVxMpzOH1PZLl4MAzzPDDpsH1Cf2GN@3ok4HSECfKQGAiXJNglZfjS/HAoY3d4AVm6ZPctmng3dBXNcZi@Bz3D0qMz3QitKLXorig@a3wik9MfDQSjgrcObvNTZOPXu176b6lUYmKfpB2D7FWHrgvlXufmLFJb17QOe5umHkcBD2QTWPPGA5kjv0B04Nt9zPicWnkPlS0pmDaFoLojSGJynwN8KCNg5nFj9MygoYDEoJbHXnKdnuo0YngpXTqWQjbC5UWl9rTnli11unA6Xz@WzWgqQVC58gHSccw838nGA8XgZGF@6sEbVFy1gr@1tJqP2aVbzFV6aqU37i4z8IkB0E8JKl31Ers4gDkSZxwC/mogGzUlCi2NUlEdRLYqiqONAO0P@2B6h3RaEkFkMiMVpZOL5wFO8DGnszvxTDlt4wVDoqP9NAUjRoJUhU1yWxPboJ84YWGZhYzjfHo2LvXibhseHefyyLzpcEHlQvV2b5rv6/DsFRP1Ssd5zUJn0zeYxXLbycwRxgiDK8jKWrX/BzsZndiPFeZMBm/5IsGyYmW0w/5NUbwXP8nzv3j5aLnbzYDgkFrt/YjuoZh9AZlhMT@mZlJaPz7OUzS7NksiRSAaygwdevIHkQDSBmGib1ktn5O3u7R9@9ejpya3j0yhk9GYwkOS17cSZoibrjcAQDWdrsUgeHKROHj848AtijnQ@JIFBexE50dblZN57RpDz1dg3s7YMw5u5W43xc75l8ya@GX0dahTpFh5a@gPSpRWRygHta7iZuF5cRq1cbh1Kc3ipEOg9vintFqqx@NV1vbFdO7Mj0ducsKQifBFRt7ASgOnM29pMIbPfzhxmLLiU7xSvEvLCdTGzvC7Kmxk8xQe3xY6d8/n5RcIh5BHKr58MiEhJTflBV9a@I651z0/Z0vmlgfy8n/ApJyGE8@l1FA@BOvXvH0QpMj8jUByP14c@7MBqSf7pMvyYPP80r@CEPH4yTCwuiZPmecIxcSPhtDxVaflDLI7SjmAl2boT93x4cQkqNOprTyfQl37qjPjJwzTN9dD0TccOiN@HEz5fbrKvToYQrkufY5OGHEFyKxAZKBkNUOX6E0gJceDeNIFHGkJ6dTx2T2RcHXZysWlc7ZvTjtUD2R6LJ0GifaRpDRYcyoeZpkP47KhMZTYvhbVV8WPcahgm@wedzDidI2DUDdWyO@Y0Fr2MxssNSB/do5fPL6JxeRkv0QmR4sjEzs2jIgP0C9p6SWKMRe30z2FcJi1KpdtSAtxuAuZnHPnXnpRKat@T6PaqKuriJ2P3ERhBjYh1h8aIxSY2PwdKZWSNncXsJB2co9T4UXI2SySoiwQf8lAZxeySibffMcOesViqCkyArp7dwc9ra8Tqmqo2wEyJxNkmXke0BxoXnqkSl6BXC1HKBLaKLAQdB8CIVxKVMzjEQX8Jj7px6TStJd50OwuNzDhIE8o1q91joVulFjVHuVQqiwJdlIolBtx3WxyqKQB7S875ujxQV5zZADSDDq0qReaC/LbEi1C6EY7IJ@KwB0AnEjr@0T8DggGs@eGM7b6Lv9i@DXUFj60pPzs9aBbjKZkFh0b0XKuDI4f8BOOg0ybunIBqmloIGq3wPtrHGA1PA2vyUynwsKoDqjDyDZEaCZPh5j2rc97UtLVcLyKKUoCQWWwAxM6apg8Oj73z53CX@C0X9j//Od7kKsc2d/KZ5uAiEc2lK/DSKjmWYx9tninKZl3Ppav3Nw1j/OpMZkYqu/Xwwux3W4e91JksswzLplJb0YOtp5aeZ1@8ml5ntOKr85GWr6uvpg25WE2eN6bs6dPP3zbfxuXpxUw@izFWiDC2d/RG1rLYWY2UC6zE8LfwvMYXXbS49LnVS5ejMoucneENrXJBTqXq0Qb8k9cLeHigek2tqTuNt2/j9QJkajo7i@Clh@zoPnlTP4lGmnQ9fmJZVoqdjbxOB35OnzX41b0R/iQSMYUJB6XO3SrDaZfcprtmrzfZN2bc3YpM8HMwFnEff@P58@doeE4Pe30cEbA5RD@NctPIRZie1v/spxvXyaunze0/@9YwZW7g5wg/371@jOYTLffRxsZHDx5ks0mgDTc//cbTr@/u7mYfJnNP67mdrJLe2P7TP9nY0PVtPbXR8DytEa2fn38u6@msrP7Zj6PNp0@/5nm1zP/xzbc1DV8FeF1gyeCTYRoY8V2En4Y61jl7Dc95l@E/mV93QmYDza3uaxZ5HQEuj8zorxmZl9kG02o7hf/y/aNXkXGkpqeeu/AdR15F8sUIN4IBbBnfdhGpRbYxWP46MktVq1UwFv7Lv4X4ta8CHPSZbcOrlvNh5WeRmlKlKG8itTwYNF2HdP@vb34zxDxcTFRJjfOf@6wOj5wt6PJOA54terYlPKpLSadSN/hPK97T7jFmj/tj08GPxT82fJhRsaHXfVxPJBINVYFHbVKklKbpZzRgE2YtGm@JzJ0Zd2Fht4BPhAv4PY8QTwFTEV9xs3AgVuMOz2@Ge77kqTz/h36OpUh@4775sFYDUZipZbZqCXo2zsplTv4UKxRlx7kvb0GRpen1iMEHBGYNBEe6qMvJZPJ@E7RKHWmqTAX9ItEzORqJvJiT1KdshM1tLOwUEaRkQR38BcLt4/Pn/@uf/@DPv09/P6Dff8BTzeyO1U1tMbzEm13U@MNqNbnmyldnZLnP0uViuZhqsuuz2Fa91jhmWvrjN9FcJnqCjYRGoc7i/ghnJHhqNXz5aKCtFuEuNW6auwmfWmChEPMoy8MxIZkYE4lAEywWfyn1C5CxNT9H8ExDD4nc@1BIsl4oyY2antOPanJak6nYSqy/6TFHyIPIDjwb8Ef/8ATWDRxF3iC3Dd@HQt1@NgJU7n4Waq8UqddTDbMBiiyr@UDub5Q3iuV8WYdCWQ24sgp05GLZaPJ9taAWVR3kyNv6BjvmTN9gCf85S9z5PFPVpjCSwcGfojjTiBT5B3hqEotcwdN4u1V/Czwskq6LCpvYVhq1hMAIPmrzfiOhXF/X1S8SlYr4364Fxgo93AQZaVwryvYXAKt@GyoHSm@1@cU2gE1s17erzh791CbSWml8UatvL8YV0e/fT6CwvQ8AapuoCsQTiU1F2aivxB5AQrgYi2adaN65Dz0EKMzr7evadX37@np7G/636X0tvuB6vX3rnz7zZ0WYuT9VobN6qnaWOhMs1AC7mqqhi5o6A0MNvhAOmiQpAkrKVIpssa3IiGmFDJiYWda29EwqN/0ovw/KUb2hYG@mqtS1fK6hcKn1QmVlhR@LrhXzcRXFUtPpNnEno8peSJEX7778n/F39u7L38c2H6poSYqktrCrUOI9Bng9ttnjx4/x99i24R9@j/ljows6PEY3m79sHsIPEzhzlxuVA2QFk/ViXm4mtJnOIttyvoDS4pduPdFo9B@90EuFKO9Y4@a/Fx44/tKy5x/90qpHirwpYfVve4xnT4qQOIBigdpUU5Ta9hDXfOGAtYJ9g8@qnyvPdhXszBpjmoJo845a9XC/WirVPA@1SClyhVBar/Dv0Wv8ezXGv9M2/h2/wj92@hr/jsf4xx638O@ph3@nr/Bvt4V/p0P8e/AK/x6P8e9ZD/@kSBVU982d9CDdTmvn2jkYLJZ2Wbqf7msd7FekTZaepWcsPXS0DphM@EuDyUp3WbrH0nba1jTwBMOYpcdo6sKnB39dgOLCn4WrBs61dJtBKgNsh@hqJPq@AbEYP5Pq0CGVX5igZKuamlbzVgNPlK/LDb1UZCoWjNqsvziLNvCoUr2UZa2ZuXH2gkU8UNArkdTZWYoPNTA9W8HD56@vm839Jw@bzRTKs7PHztH8/@hoGLau/R8eOY@PnKED/0dHR4@ZWUvcTyj34anWEtvisxOpVXbOygqKAF/eRFLbO2e1jILmfAJEiI5uiQ985hDhW9s4k6IM9J7LCmlXlcuLymWFDIEVDM1KEEAE4wZwrAitDFwqvnp2Cc/FJTniC42Xz88CEzeknl@eYS8Duo/BP6ivYet/hX/r/13/j5@xWL0B2lLs6no7Rk8c/@Lxq@ura/GuxWMxYYltwx86gB2jXF3X0EiBrsBUj8Ub8etr7gbvWHybA6xhGts1ijwPCLU/EqRJ6fJX7L/uF9MWzxkeam7M5/3PzqbpdLzS8g9Rxjkv4w1Nv8YrdCXOZquuNf70x3RU9k6cAuWylYq2xbhFz@qVSta3FYqVStG3bMZipdtPLb2j5UFdymbj8UoFLDs@2DRYA7BFAOtbcgDV9Iw21ftK5OrwiA6RBjGRi8QxR1wwxNJ01jxeWxKVy/K9ezFxHerObvzePb2UfvMmcBmNwElbcGo2O5bbbKJ75s0buSnTPHwpB/Z08c0bkGXRuOPGnuBtN5BQTNHYR3qN0iw5LhCiAN5MS@lzLPqGZ4zHbuy1NUrKuP7Jk@N0GUU67bhn0Z9971vfOotWq7Iik2tWQwCYCsttb@eztVo@C@Z8ESglb17xe1l6iZIWv95MyZwaTN6MRoSXVizEuWyMoj80jGynBhXcw4ddXUeo2Fk2F4@BdI2DtnYdwT/urJVK3J1l87FioiT@qhtxVgMtgv9hbzeTyG4Vtu43GP1Nlz0okitXZlW7rl6ZZRw0vK60xVWDuGHSvHcvUwKaFtOVM6nZfLh7uttsVmVZxvYQXuhIwl3CG45GbrROBZ4rNeqYv8ZZNFqu3Cfm0Io5FolWRDglCq0EK5aIDJLVxd3QkHdJE0MJG5JOX3xJYjBpAxwj2KLPf08f7e7tnyb1bVCK9IPdvaR@8uxBRENrbm4n7wzaj/d3Hx49gwhPH@3vnux/fPjZ/rOn4O6xy/njS2Dxnn/DpiX2S/Zceum@NkzTMCem2bycTC5fsZeW1bSAsIOJZVlOz2We2TRNcwTB/KcCv7blGS9fGu6IHvbuR99596P/5t3vfO/d73zn3e/84Gdf/uA78PsJ/L7Hv9/7N6Ucvn/25T/73Xe//Tvg@B/g90fw@@nPvvzNb/If2f8Yfv8p5PbH4hcKx38SwPqVn335/R//7Mtf/SH8/qX4/fD279d@uvz3g2@v/mG87//u@jDf@7fw@z0Oyw/7vd/mbvi9Ff63ebhf/eG73/h3/P9PxR8af@fdb/wxvoTln/7wT//Tu2/9e10v/um/fvft77/79rfeffu77779j/V3v/mvtXT49bvvfvAHf/WHv/dXf/g/0P9P6P177/P/7of/9C/@l7/43/7iD8Xvp/D7d2D66V/8e2DYv/2DH@H/9//gb//oR/j/P/2rv/2DX//bX/kfyfBb3PB//8t/w99//Wv/8W/@xXf/6qff/Jtf/@nf/NYf/NX//qv/52/@x7/@b3//r//7b6Hjb/30r/7oV/7yW9/5y2//87/81pcr3t9Z@/7yPdy//AdweX883wfO@@TrQ12@/IXw@ftQY54K8Alw9z9595u/DAz@G4y9@85PcNkv/Fb8/0TXKMxPuO3/Awb9dp7RJw0m@P36u@98D0n03wGJ4D@g13cDy4IPt3x3bgGy/osbkSJmebHxLOrFxBb0MLZKJdGABt7bFPNnX/7zHwdJ/PIi1AU/SPG7KKkW/L6LMu7dj7757sf/@N2Pfuvdj34FWzMlW0ruJhVt/QpGaAKV3HuEw4D59wkHAT/H1nSaoIFXJfH55@D4ufD8/PPPpembFK4zv/8GXD8nJ/4w7gV@THj5fsId172Gw3Bj2jduovObcNJIhgQmmyBVYMvXU3IZNk0IjKZsysTgJAaabvFxSnyTK3pPJXzN/@fGqcQSGEYMaibmRjKIeCIJbpRykExiOvXpRYoT48rKFnehOSlKN1timIPpNDGFHikYIIUEeD1IsGq1msCIVY4PWDlqtSIjVBKJKuQbY/M4yWYRQUwfEBSIWU0cs@ZWdcojJhBezSdHQkKnY1nT5USx@hASrE4fMoSFwAnsixfVWrE6rSG4t5weiWniAeGEwKqJae0t2KsEM4HDUg/fAirFaiJRK2KCmElePMkmL6QcZY7ynmAJUQbwxWHenfuMfSRrRZnPj2wgwXhofCfmoXdoxm4H/M8SWyI79O8b6bdFBN@gpEQqjPvvkKq4w7VHDABwFUVVVQY/nAXcYffBe8pBJShZ@CQ4hARxBHFA4ABsiGWRoPJNkAXSj1S3PvhJ1CSem83NTSlSkzPyEc0XJaDX7p6X@d0qb3jXqMzkfElGZ5PWkfPcmZtPadhh6@EWvDX439@g5d0JViG0NqM4PBhlPD32UYL/7t/fYh9B7uk7d5OYksg4WRyqx4xuJxKyDqnWnIT0BUg3CdiXAL2R1GmVZqkSUjLJmFqNoB87OjoSqJHDF1UpAdyvZzS047TCZDKJQAxVTarJpPiq9CUHVRhU8hVfdRNpTsOZTNezFejfVBg6sXB3RIN@Kzq@ffsWCouWeJQPoUfJxGoPPVskT3Dg228Hg5m/C0HPliTenWZant9@HqPLEeMsLrEY24pLfDEwR8J/YlG9WIyiKQ5losa2/MU/eU3yhxYjNUTUf3gfr5iL@557R2zv6PHj/Seno0aDSSbdWmk2R67TNj1vnWCOYbzdJw/5XgG9lEc0IvU6pnxa1lEsSfvlNAnNw4fHhydlxmkiSigWQIpXaARZkKKkSZHR6Pl2RCyQkPEaFUc@wXd5nv@YXspggrWKFGmb2C0BhsN/VpEee70HzhT68klZTmp57KLFaeCVSV93yuXqWy1bkOBL9gnDA7/47mConbiiXN3eJqJJtSuFxs3RCAWcl2o1sdKIaVLtZP8UIpweMU1Pqwx6@lfZgp7NZXN6Jp/PFXQtmy9l87liBtqafDqn61opmy0VS4VrqfY5m6qIqwLmQXVg2r1xfxPX98hnaTlEj816Ool/eiYDb4CY1HKFxsbG4EpBBM@ILa5wodY1WK8UpMBX4GHSVyT2FXCCB9LA1VdMLH07PKqI9Ud4DkeML0KStRxU7rh0BozEwUmj8FMZQfWBzn7oJ0U2vvGNMavVoJOtHB5IEZBSfeavwVGsjtpXiY86E9ck3x5jHeszCy/XUTuWNxoYM6ibaVWKXF9fdwHS4QHTazpZeYwOvq/b5NIC8/XUkP7/532fiKLUpO1RDRhwOzUCowHG7HbKAGMLjLntVAuMFhhL2ykLjJNaRktvpybQLkjb/NQqhptiq/LYnOIhedxNrnnmoKvi9oKqTAno8rY4BbIm4tVwn4ZjdKq4cxLX18fiV1Kn2nHadIOX1FFbTmemeuPZANfhDxy3GgX1K@p7WHgpKu4nq9ZZQx05I2gk9VwhUdfSIJPxpxWTerKjtgem4e7kyrkiWoLZkp1cunxp2R3nUv388aNPxuPRsUlL/XeypXJHxaMpcBP5TrGcyzXqdVlO1CmZBl4IyCuksrEBTGwaHQW@Xccee4pebEDkjuVWq9HoTkbTypl0UboOMi8B2TBHNQnjJTAnSSTdleD3su3YULfKSSNpXVGuy91u93rrKjG3SMaVwm1Aj2vFSLauAmtFCYUrs0lSseae4GJ0oWm5EhNFZVnPFeVKvTK3F/JypXEt3R@aHcvA5f1n6avbsfIggzjUCCR0xqTrsus443LL7DquOQ@Y0fJ@QI7Q7QBZ@TpI7iyNKV7dTi6PgYCGnHLAp/yEsBotaauD2GzsQ2tYb2z7Z4chf@q6omeUjKZoGfy/w6Dj//uH1@FfxzfEyujSKe6ffQLSE5oHmz3Co8rHDjt1HLqV7oHZXhFir2/Q2r091/G8v0eYB4Z9zr0eWvzQqsDrEwOvo/CG1ri/IsSz0RA3RpruPxiE/WELEKRqTQEewMsdOM6yAAX27OmKXD4OjokEYvBzIiH48eHHn5yGvqf7u3ufSHn24OjJwxufnAiUY4/2D04Da4H7@lFzAYiv7z96dNMqPtmjZ8fdiePiTzo4epadvwIn3A4mZeFZDBQ4ExDxQis0zhUajN5guYJv0CRcUHwPumb3hDGXnxvTaHzO97pZXrDAlW9qLEun/gY4g6EAapmszfe/Yl@RTj8RKqNWKEnSiNnOJSukWccZDAy85bO7AY59Azf2mKgEDegyWkz60nEHnUurY25Ij3EPUUnDqwwRCekTADKctOmoAWss4VlaHbx/Eyc1WoOJySZ4x@0KR/igExpdq9eH5uXS8QNILcNg8PvQB@Kb4We83mHM0yC3Wz6D28GliGSMjUixcu@e9tSFmlJLl8s987xc258Co7JnUHEMNydn1LZ8wNRmxGA9q@41RlBWmWxeQ50IlFhQ3VgxWTxmqMihkl3XQZE7S6eMrGNX2GbKGdW8aPravIZ2KpGFZmjcbVeg8cuVoQD@@l/85O/@5NdRLZW2UvCKaLKMq5o3NEklvVkvFXPFUkaHJErFbE7L53JJTU9Ct6RQggTTWlHLF3MlLVnMljLAjSXwzZUKUoQvGUttEUj4lgGs3caL97ZJ9Vb7NSnCJ7jY65gRZxEjsE@YbEIcGa9a98a0bXLLqsp6lmlpBr0ugGiwNoscHOylDw5k@QFacFp/Ly3LHbTkiul04YEsm@SzV0RVQnZ4nCKeXyKPuSWdfrAnyxMOAI/@lOU@WvbzOGgjyxZa9nYPDjCdLlp0jA/BzrkPtwx8SwGC2WjJZGjUR5ZfBeAg3C5PKEuY7qMF00SfA@6zB36y/LGPTzoNEI55OA7hEz@vu7uyfMgtu7vos0cZz3FUP0XLLj2y7IIFqoYs98DQc6FSynILjFhBZLkNpvbMADe85hDPh7THhizPOIGQRLI8pdBG@1yWm747JvPJJ58Y/XHH7PFn5vJvG1ADH2s62T9offxxq9drubPd/Y@P0Wdv7xOjO5u4rV5LRGs14XEgDvicD2c3H8DxsNk0Bkt9PgUf@4ZPc9Y0Ebem8QpwEk8PExk298BnD3yWzQ1yaPAMIWgLnwdD@D4wWuTjP@RD32mrJVeQUVGbpbuKoc7QtcHJodF2nQrap9UNxqKxaHJWz6cbFfJgQ9Bb05VruqQ4hm8DRwniV7P6tJpuVKfVgs4XlXRj8tlUz1lycmO4o5Vy5Q1jR9OziWkZN0873SiLKtoOi2n3tl6z2JP4jp7JluWznR1FrmuNHV0rlvOFL7Ymshwv43snUyhDwHQU@tD4itcLjZ1CLhSlUEgYKb1cKMQr10COMTTKLRQszVjs0jTO43FEF/t6kAV@RfKM8mlVurFpclrleLFZvDKtahV@dBlL34LVwXMyJ@2x43KIPQA33UmX6RJmWSsVZUg/lYrF4yCZSIjAd77o7PnXTs9PTz@XUHTVRB/0Kb/ZsyKsH3@yp0K3VNjwfEv1AHsNjqvuoWBZ8OHHL/pOp6Bcq59AKwgdC98NN7S4zkDdn7bNEXY9fA//1DJVnDWlnn6yAOcEOuA8ZdwPXKHjJOy2yfD4T6vDjGoNTEaHxQgrZsQvqf1t1mrVZnXI71GuBbE@ZXQ25hzMocdxD3YpU/Qr3OQhPJrV9HWlVZ1GpgCnWWWK9mLodF7oiXalg6d@Pqg@wMiVJnxbFbNq4m3SckSudHfsKmMT2zO65lPTxT33h0eboA3gzo9Yl5nxTXZGd0/voQp@rdRcZs8xezIZxgyl1oovOoWsSJrY1/wsX9FWJJxtv650qyz2RbzyCqzuJot11AfxnWylE3vAmnFwSb/ovugyneWzFbqOL4aQoBIRbehO53i19ikoMBzwebkMiIgyPgeYmBKAtTrkYcRH1nWlXR2wmMKmLE7kyVZ61TrGfoOvbUWWG4pSf9OQaoryXKpBPa3MIkbVm7ToqGiWbml6Ol@ZgptWyFb6ULDGF9OKWx1NXLMyAKsYkOE7rowKkBOoBmBev4m9@@VvxreVXJW7VQjUmwHoDE21WZ1WbDx8BliimqmCR6KeTSehYwqvQhIaZB2UgHwyk8wmlQK6QmuczCXBUQNVIDaIyYzJyfQ0rWpJzdSSUPtfWJ0XLJ48j4HOQSQDy9jZx6uswQUKCbmSrPA1WDyhbw0YlILDjG2F2BQkRQUzBjTvs5GV7COoY9MYUIx4XGGZrdhgM4ZhNk8no/16o1zen46@Bl4x5dVOPlFIJ17H45XYRrzqma@kWkWqoVShXI82gGfFWBXzJsM6lPF4Uyvo5Xq9hTkspJOZdAayZzXf9LblmtxIpjfyGpTQNSM9hnGBwXWZuTYyd2ui0oz3wjOtpFcklZZlUIpaTC/pK8Yn4xIuCBQApZEQdkhhFjuT/T2HsWi0oEej8WgFR7U3ZDEYCRKOXzEPojZ6T9uRQX@Sy3JJxwBzQUnbytJhFepawo4@y5akyJV0fXW9DT3VFK3PA72QbZBJUWv3pUiZMdDjzsTBJakNxj502V9iu/YF/57hGmOAK9HhcaAy0mIc08LuFfsMt9DusCggZrjDuq5nGnW9AO0byEw/qK5rFRyzj@AyZrUGlPeuAL/tRA13n3zKZjMjofiUvcdYL7EpUaYjN8m@W93tHe9WfNseDhueSbIsV6Jy5CoaiV7DnxS5T1tedL7lhUVCm174eti2CfR5GyGJwfau/DGkMl5hEjPKXD7UG/G3T6zBVTGj8KECEFjX15HNFJWI2DlQ@fSFnoMysh1/KwF0b3BIBpquXA7HPCOpFyPvG3ox8/jwyH7oHpiM7yQoZptyLcLSmoIL8ytl4ZrjS4blUlGX9fNkhN2PVCLsXIlqZdptwEYnpS8KXxS/ePzs6NnRgRQ523iz4eB4OPPJwt7aX/0aBIxmslHGzqqRaTVbEeuvajVF29bxSKACK4Ow72p5Jf2mxtm3Rh55HXze/fIPs9PtIth10F7LUIS5hF6raVs6i0dG7778fTwL4mr/s91HLOoZM/Z3f/JjvfB3f/KvaFVT9Lri0eBrIQIh0ajlC5Grq9HV1TU83C8XaUQ4UtlCHMx8oF@LzDc0lFOGsVVIZPX7diUlwmoFLR7xlIiYzijkIt4b4aWni@DlzzeQk5zHIojsH1s5Xbu/jUyhBfug2Hxa2/RKwBXFxy/eMAaWdq3T61k6mVIpVn6rsO23yjZ7i@P1b5UN9qJawzlmDXdP@SPUW7VaDaGwaC2R2ooyPQd@9etKI8FojBv6el@Y5pZ9tsjRZxu4IH3RacuGP3PLoz@M4zt4YPVt5tZLj8mxrXgq1emIk4O2TZarAStspQCzs/i7X/5NXc//3Z/82pvmm@bnOnTiSqW8pkd@rv385xBgzQ5@vwdGQ/m41R4NQc@NrbjeGnqoUgTvPO8yHt7vx2HPDdUHq2dDzxxt0gWqPFRKTX4sVCdGwbZwg2@SFGg6tCVekaRA0SQF2e21kwSDbeHVA1BNpSvpK@gF7SqrguSUvjIHBQ5DaEmddtMbTNwRbRKIUTytkWT3IAqk8BU8cWuDNiYL8auAxEpt3Y7KUfaIaqQesaHpeXh@FzQo0lcgijgmDm9UNnAPPYa0bJD3KgYhPMmjU4e0G5D2gEdokmuMcs8DJBnHjkeyQYmWvgJ6AVHBAnWBWdsQoAIy5itAAMhDTAC2GmybZeLsykokKvPDwa5xuTQeZGb4@3cljIbQOrhf3I9cwXDgBMo7XkyEfCFKGDS1kKMPhMPg07lVUP8xOtlQ/6IN9u8NCmDRYTYxyhq7d2@OVbVqdeKMcoTwz60Rjj9ROdjLcQVgftfpo05ZTjI8dq3iuwZsBxRPELrAdQo/b60SispktF5LEvy/N9MiR94oKvKoYAZEefFa0QaSQWQkOy/DNtuuMk0vxFmAfBtwbxNSdNRX0B88m36k6p/7nteA4c8j/rHfIIhOw2N6gm9vbuBm0AJO8MxlPMaHCwOx8Zof1IMC7XDsxw5iQVasAYXuWi70VWg62T/1K5bR4hhtfkoa4UELoPUsw5XIuTh@KBaGZvA18Hwrkc4GndHRdqBAvZFj04FYdHgHLvIGjgAZJc4V4mhP7Es8o1@UDUUOY@TRmULI@YgxHfBFlxtSXJyfbbnQofVpk2RmT2XtYYfpJRYjRqPzj@wAXJwiEcItUHyRxq2BOQSUTkyTtth45VSqBwrSpEWHQD22gK/6Bxa0KraXEvdIpi6tcyt1imcMK04Xd@LwLfUR1Kmw@vGpYHHg0sBxztnAOjf5UG1s4UACj4HqD/prEig7/wFhy7gsQc8kWRq8kzwU/ArwKXBjMRmKuxGbxW9/M9pGrIkl@oYaGcvFOyIvDDtEX3reSKK36808/0gTOpgD7Gogck1xmEE1ituUg1M6JHE4S5XOBVFxCmAUg76nf6gJGkEtNy8Y9lslbGNAaLb94wGwFkNuv0INANU9qFl4vtnYLeOhFoCJ24m1oeoJAW@zj1hGlzAgP3FGnA4DMLDoq4vQwQ@iYj68cQcKRuXbz0CuQO0cdsAPt1ML9sP4Pnejmc6em7M32xDgsNGhtKqMVwvfkgtZsHYgP1PWN8AzDxguwWQjJicAbEKOyxx0EP9mdM7tEsmSMrsNKckQgiA1QCFVwb9EloUO05fA44Hh8fMwxUlol5eXKh3JN3Et1fTwgHkPb8ZNjXoWqMdOamwOR@IqLwuvcBRw5yaF3yuB9yXvTOmm4tK9Gf9KUterioUbsWjXi2LjeIHnp/eGdJQPnqHjEUMdWHT3Qjsm1ppw/tMbySuf/8rIf0oxeo1AGEMw0@Qs2U4CsGSrfZ7sXnYqwuOCKiQAh1I0fUc8BtP1LUPPN1mjbhDCGdOWCt/eGpzTdCZAkvko6jxpnkM/5My3CvvImkIk27xku65rzGLkH8fQyMCxGak9bAbNPvmAEZoZdsXPZLSm9VljIfo0iA6Nmt/7YS6e0yNdrQfKD@hE/yn3n4L/lPtP54n6ydanDa6SodM1Zge5Ho9380MimJkf5pofZjn3IcigYzONg8CQswW3a/i1qxTbpze3QTlWfcYAnhgBwc1Yqv7FWf2sYXvm5VYjkeoBs8tECChxAF1vEE0vO4EZqT@4GIwcb8HJxlP9oFUSeKNTuy@4gfMK5jEoIGIMTi8LD2LrDcUiAK4QiAwDBNTDwBNVg91xzIpXggNhyRMYpy7PacwRqwtkGqR9CS/hBuoSJz0nbBhQIwQI3YMsAZrgw/yaw68T8aXDcxdvTffDKnQDwhAPBIo2okDJG1WFy5oKFVIIK0Xx0QSyo7pavZkV3x@Kon7DK5TNa1H@YfQ3Phj9LtSL5dgTw/IGoyKFqwquZAMVQlQXoiqrVUPlChiktoyB6ULLtc/1U9FaQzJbKb@bwdPBLHiXeEdqLFT47TgvH9rkJttyOWCFWbUKWZxVebXk9cInKSd4EM0T0WY@I4j4XIAAjPTSaKaINg1Hm1arXHCw6YpolyEkp4TklEfhoacrkGyIaNB7Ci7XxuJpgHaK6@ZkgKfxZhTUoJHM8KJUnJV@iYeV4YSlSHMuc4gLBA@hio181m4sTb0eQjoktG4AQEa8BaDDbyYrSzcFnqYEtkBGcVL6MorbBBtwWQEMRiK4wg/0jAVMRn1gUPjlBLUDUHflRF2SNRrixb80/8lJ39H/abcd04shtUXHdPLG3z@IYwMpG6qgIe1DS2dRIGNP5pm4Un5B54jgJZ59B7S61qXDYkuUbXBP@bfRp1oDp5UaGri6BO8rCu6oj/v9B5weYfdHztgYO9lsmXeaLGK7ZenzPoPVsx085jx0kC/oeh3H9OzoGAq17fRsyzOTDM9bOzdFt8MU54ZLYT1ZGB1PksRwJO/GImjOV6jqNpt4g2KzGcOVcfFysOSWFsohe0ajEvZ/wRSKD@JJAD0axZzWS7M9jt8NE8@cFtFOrfZ57GgkPKOQyC4DGdYG/R98@6DBMM@Z9xzp9FtUpVvjGN1/0HeGTg@0vomnShj7BvjDOWxEyBiNCJckM7BLWw6dPE61JNZOGnER9dMPjso@1WNGPIivLwJYIEaSuTdpjJR1lyTXXJkcj@and/Lh@J6E8T1Zjy/1wm/izLvmVe75YUlnYnMIEHCORuZuNDDrILc6t9BZQCVwRr2KR3hvFDu0equDmO5C0F0RXO0CfyQDmwe2APHPVtF/fQH60ffft/gMvFb2ZAbyZoiLCmN0b4Dnz3PGIPhhPC5FliQXsPbD90wLwuKlQAeoQoAaS4LLxoM7oWKOoNvtBcfJ@4Dv4HlcMHWL72kVVZV7LsHJvUiyc311ET1sdsyBMTM7MREyGYLr5/gYOmwkr94v4yjoSOg5vK8Xg7YrHvhCM45E54HKK1jGSF7E46vZigexAu6hkXLC8HA1/dD/lmjGIb4qH62GfkA0GsHh2AsLhz9Hs9GMnw094BeKCDnK2x9ekriV/26CAB3EcTjJebLxdeLzOBZk6T1ahCCsuphlPLrVh4gHydwuww8j0d05hcINRar6pSwt3nOwvMStdSUe4gqfJ/kU0vux5F1M9948F2I1DmwuwvY@rAm5BRmXZrTbsTBE7rK2xBz7lkxANxqns1e0Ks0lAjWISZJubFF3m/SLuIQ940P44oDTZ/BFgD1z3OQM5ecNx7TEPSyMfIbGKKS1CBdQ0gFKiIqc5AKNUCjJN0Pwq@sgzfbKNNu30mwvpBnUgMUkQ4Gk9kKSohSweNYVwcDsjldIZ/TCvjN81olteGzHcHG04ipqRctWkkUvomUQyFEzWt6PgVCOdqLlh2TwouUTMpxHy5@CYV63om@iZb9aYAAXrGS4j@5ChKO9HS3vxeLX0tg4Nz0/XTVaDsoUwuxwK1EESIH5Bq0Rp9hsR2Rz7JrQsJFSmWTIMV4Su080DpOkXxr@@c0ldAMCeuIY5xYFZgmmLTQaoRaDpwPNhn/C9pKaXBat@f7RAS1tCoJgMgno44XjEHhQwyPRRWHEEUNfmtGALyCIcrO8HCMWasneEx2ROnAoFfJi@kQ9lfSBToz86xC4MU@ErqsR8f3yWgTBC/D98MTIq/C8hY6fHGGEc7LxJWghUV9E12QKy3oRF1H64RKise7FQHgvsx@ElxKBDcl00OFocg4TGzmjRSYhX1wDb4Xj0KAcr5TIvTeikVQQNXOFNzmLnKFgCFf@@LrshOIhagsiCD3r6QavZUG7QLIYveayLqSp8soHKIRkDtRws31OVwE9FEYKx8VNktqKVc2QH5cnSZJrUUxCZBXPJJoYY5560Hndx5OKPqz76sec4lhLDAGEYgapcPnqfID@7nD93VeofSLcSGCZYr28Kb2tXq9tZW9gPpgne7sA0TPJHsaXKkdBCnOSQ@8gpJmv47VbKj4u@eBKPk80gH5D2/fJFvQJ7qDbzb4Fh4Vagnux6Hiug@O5vppQtzWSwYXqKy0qpiTg8IwHmM6zth5XnvFlRYw@NL5tDD64gN3FAg4XHsKjDLg3SM5ruTuxaZXLvG6D2OYuKFK1MuOCnKZLg2KeO4K4p6nbYNoWHI6axw@Pnjz6OjS6hUIhLtro2Rw/rLU41hq04xwyrZMO2oMl3RY9ibd74GQ3DsfTHegbZ7Z8S5ZwYQ3KgAGp@Own6nhcyLKQPL9RdyEeDxuiqIB1Pq8GxoJUQlXHwCbbEnQdA0HMcWzLEEB89RbonaTeWpzusWg28d7rZpOar2YTFy81m6IVw6LxZ8TjP49spCaeS/du8ktYLiWJDhNgD4/Y8092T9npJ/vs4Nnep@zrR8/Y890np7gp/OmzB48O9xj89p@c7DNpYaUkXliFHUqg60OzbeK9gnigW5YR5D1nNONyJ7YX5@4nxpB94rRNnKba9ozh/T63qLY5rvFY@9AdneEYpkWXkg2tMa63oBu1oBuLyk2H9u3hsn4GYVvQpx1in3fodKyuBWEl7PuOLNPzt3qxgQUlCPLW37Wb5EoSXp5FS4fomjtcgXUJ0Q0Ij3M3AMbg66/oanHL4xHMjsoE4YLngyl4un/8@IThsQN7R08eHp4eHj05YQdHx2B9@vXDJx8DPQ9PTo8PHzxDLwr4@Ojh4cHh3i45cATSKsON/y8n3ngtCioGJ6q0z3Hmm26QD2yLo96owbNLg3Yweiw6sVH6WMbAem12ohVp4qH6grsmaaqAxTZ3jz/@DNp8Zr7CGU5/KpjWH8jPPLrEbTPNtik1qCw1qG8VUV2h2VO0OM1HDGcM73QwK7THP0bmJPOB0yKejmUyeQ/XqODYNz8KgOqyDxoS2gDYCMpfsFJldBdLNJrcJpA1SK09cPAwR54aX0QoLBj1vr/UpCIRxcRaGQSKWxcObRwP0iqBA/A9OOgi2bHLA7BM4MADsCx3QFX0ENeOsJwIMRkfTVA8szx3eDkcHdC0MCsEDg8M6sUWBU683KhIDRbcZYUHIwzoxh0@ykM3ARpe27Ioikfh8TaawYBXDJPfgwYykU8l0to2CCmDsOniVINY9sYvDEVf4AZcJ2R0xx6LVeMqO8XFQaZt8buOegPD5kug5kt3iPdYEY@@qYoVt1ZwRxBtBhk5xIB4P9kiHkG8h0IrNN83HsR8cCtFQ6yRpHv6/CVodyHw4BYCvwgYAKQs9HTa1FLRplIE43QFK8c8BzgSx23fhsMDO3cmbXMhgli1FXtpvX4dF0ROLvST/HWKhB0U0WvTBbWSpjK7jgt1nMQq3aqCUrDdd0Zji5dhbDEHNONEzRyExoYNUntRrS2khnS4maLt2KFEW8DFK1JtAVO@T6rE8XzuPBBf8ys2gfOhEebr7hAdo4U3qM/nzpI4iXRp4vALKMI0V46Dn7MxYcL1T2kuO94yvKWvWK09fHCmvH2RxKv6uFjgt2P6iw7xB4yJaUH1oHk@WrDoot4lapp/xZI3aWFssQZPSEus5T4w6Af2LejX3W9WAj@@3Pi2O26XuelOjm/eVHksBSWTuDDV68fm0i3J6n6SSYrTYGIJSEh2ArIg62O@S5JgBvL6Pm6RwVKoAEVslCPYb79xgZEQIX7uWpMuSBZxj6Qo7gB@nNVoRcX8Wl3c5BIuj9QXsQfVRC2emi8oYSFyxnwRnfQh/z/FPe1WGzuSv@mnEG0S3NBu2yQQgjG5BkziWQIZDMnNMcS3sdtOzzW2r9uAfRPmzO6PfYHd//sI@yrzDvNrn2K2PiS1um0I2ew5N@cEd7ekUqlUkkqlqlLRcQyzFFqvZsDtPwwO5u/Hg9t8EDteHr4L2v6D0L4Lt9zq/bB4WTJgPR7sXx8Ay4vb/wkstN29HzAvkrPQNKdr5nSXMtqa9uEaf5npOxp7AAbXXtSgaKBGbdd9OqJWoZOzXMAxwcQCUf10v3pyImzen0BZmPdwy9CW0yDCXhTvYmvbsE@TnaeFJr1Z1sKT@pKwaFP/HhrMc4l3z1QhZRBX0kNPFvEF0p1wwrOeXFlIhCDre5oQFeWS2H1Rc1DUkIDvYA8IyMadZjTQmtvMDC8@YWQagUu6uSwbmzb8ZGHNazfezjiamoBMmyC/i54l8/vvA8vHW6oeFrAwLg82uA2SNKw3sE@oQ8VDyOh5yR58oFtUl6KRPQvYGUU7NPwqJCXsH2coYiQWwlkWNqZ1KRxL1Fg@XlJiDhkk4jLgo6WnTGSLZkhQUzx92TY71IkXvWxyCQIhE@/r@8nkCih@cVfSN8hn43WyrAVyc6wtETYNheUFamcl7NL9mZ6gLfRGenpIVwWz7YNV5f5/quJVIlGTovncxqhEgLyxvv7sW7DTrVDFcz8Km9eQ9Pw5vhrC/j4GGU0jUu8D59aOXJUeM8ADpGPTejVgUgVB1JmzpiTaTouRiR/gwnohQAZDluMViOlaHTFJ4TYfOq9IJnTKMtMGYwjrhvKomaH@3cPV4YT8zfoWv78@HmyYCU0H79Aq/@1gFAWxV54RUMX4hK6syW/BaNSnbOzPdIVQsuTG9KCzHXnbscErtwoT6bzNbElHeiex2a2rdA1UCakXPbz1FLV7pbR6L1csmU09qB1WxQqFEuwkdJH2yHaMuWcx7D@EAM3BpJfA5YN8@J5EW/AfcHAVSCATefNliTbON3EjioDU3KBrZKRZqJxbi@ne70Qtv4/RPVz7SSRs9ykUJC1s9fjAmadZL5QS5QG5aNjPQinXznk2FYVvqNBFSEkQ3Jv43Viw0FNDWUo@cFe9ny9uFjZeWtS6vjt2rxovL9yVVtkWsPj6/avoenTb/rU7@HzTET0x/MvlpDX9/Tch1p@LZ1DX2lMOI1vcKOcpBucL@LspXhaIcyWCrygk7rkthMf34wmxLOJ9eGlR8N1wtGneQg@JFJeKlSvFhehiNy5fNTYuyv1yoXTV6F@U0MlvvFoerxZXs/jhKayiMMfwyXxjfIFrqql1Dfo3Aq9NpevtpGuIINcQ@PLWH4WDw8rR64Q2DgUAVIFJW29SqPONpwtozYa@J14/uM1KNZkrkGMtFJCsBfIKKqJ7O@mTUR3TDgEz6BUXpNloQn@njrVQ8K6H4wGlqIiByFria/jVWlBuTAXSKECWRqjiCtJF79EkzpPFgyH@OmUr6lyRxbUi@k46BogGlqTp0D63bfQpRESlL1fjwoq8wG99RiTwit@vVExsb9OFv8BqkUdaPDTl8EfkMFG4wEc8AIGfIZ02YBUkuUfk9mFB8/G9iA/8hXRUY/KTIQN5iyRFTEHzb/GF/Juo/DYQgAm/wDKXJ1WcUvICQZJ9B0m5gJHHkht/PGZAt0rulAVsLMLm@soxcLIUJxphtZJM8H3hFsnJtIJ/sgW5Ir3NNEPndzg7kYTOqeVbhLSkLqWkHfzpxcWyRrGcKqYyG6RY@CY1UNMF26O3AQyrqdgLej1AmmmxEJMDH8m/V9a/quuPGljnhUae03Mz6blEusfpjFScy4MFPs60ZWayM1/ifHfCjrO5M3WVBQkvHvR0ywORJM5beihv5I0HzTDOvKO7krlSJ2wnEnJGyqc5vc8pi4kymsF1eoPTJX@vyZ7XWCby/pSsH38t2UEBGc9KW5MUl3r9sPfKkrfDyhRkMxuoKQQXx/4mtuNBKX0w5XQCEhzq@WnY7pRjKKtFNePQmLF3tn@yPSlkvMqm0WAvxpmBNWeMGFSiOleJcBNyWIR6KHnRAEEwkdGEGrk7qvBUFp4aYDHXoqqWvSBnBjg0LT3Ey@gX@RX/qMGeRE7ly8xPXGDMJ9x49m5OEogm3UV7PpmSswm6i/BH2agHVpG47mka4vxJ4sjQAus6A/bB7qAafFHPE@ZEoWaKGbrrFEnpOENRse99XYiJd9Y/8yvWax9k7GEvmIgKbjN88sKyEg7u4yAaRxjmicLSRNfDYQ9PHUnguyUXahkzZG0dj1tiiMbK7lk1tOzh/C4@SYd0KOSJY4R8iwYicUJ03e2iMxl6wA5ucWpFjUs49qxKf8oKDRgzz9bYzTwQ1xGfmsJuv2siwT3HowcpHQ39VuBZIKNFIP1Y3NROKK9pJH06@o1gIDFY0rYs68/XYevXvdd4nvuiWHhWNEh2I4@DC96z57GDFRBJJawVQIxdLz63LONsuMVnwzkE6IpDXOjfA28GN0G/H1gVWDEoYwRCaxSMboK2Z1kngT4ERrjIyngyiX7Yg@tRi5U7IHT5wIzoJRy5fBwGHIa/uD7zcXGLzspcCw@t4tNm6OqbsI0EVB4nnQGeDtOBBYYJYHpgoatgDERZcUQSJTp7lriQ7HKFiiigBsY5Mc4mNBn6g3HYgp4hTZbVA1B8DBJX1m@nMIH6Wj0fnYO9eQige0xMAYWAOkp6CAdLHpp/Fw5CNkydsfuqZ/Iw@w1orMBwD0YhzL4xgalXqJiBO3Tw6ZtaXdSPD04/VE6qAp7fnRy/r@1X98XuRzrjxoNyCosr3hwfwuyiT9P51PwYPtiVOpS0KcGqHH0U1Z/fnVTrdXF8Impv3x3WABqAP6kcndaqdVfUjvYOz/bp9B0giKPjU3FYe1s7hWynxy7VqopZcTlxfCDeVk/23sBrZbd2WDv9SDUe1E6PsDI81a@Id5WT09re2WHlRLw7O3l3XK8KbJi1X6vvHVZqb6v7HtQPdYrq@@rRqai/qRwephp6/OGoeiLISMBo5W4VsKzswhYWa6J27tdOqnun2KD4aQ@IBwgeuqL@rrpXw4fqz1VoTuXkoyuB1qt/PoNMkCj2K28rr6FxVvYbVIF@2Ts7qWIoJKRE/Wy3flo7PTutitfHx/tE63r15H1tr1ovCevwuE4EO6tXXYFX3VHVAAOoBenwvHtWrxHdakensGacvUN7Bwc6@QMQBrCsQNF9IjCaQWBrgUjHJx8RKtKBOsAVH95U4fsJ0pSoVUEqoEXF3qmZDSoEIp6azRRH1deHtdfVo70qJh8jmA@1etWBDqvVMUMNDTI@AutApWfUauwnwIsfgVktxbkudaeoHYjK/vsaYi5zAwfUa5JbiGx7byTNPQyMayhRwgHqDPwrU7HSmf10E2CcyVmNzHwdjY6YtHe8X4UVWcatsuOEM1h1NlOhlMw0WGl0IrwmQta0g8vrbjPsdwboY6qLseLjKuq6eGeMg1dnnFsPXM0h9StUIJNpNt9XmrDRrTebjvuYkgk0vlVCqsEfyuXINuJtALjzRsXP1hbTfTtBqJ2n8qCTDPXwAAJzMvWfsumbfxU4Ip9vB7IYOu8jYKU6ivjY5DMepcDUSM6OeL9HXCVpJug9lOxABbMKvNdqop4ULSMp0yCCP/2v8QsvDsYHmJ1Z3ZXP4yaW0Ah/D1Q1XAmFRKA/MiJB2KEqvSgIfu1mC2Z1uOf3uoNBO@s4qgzlHcM@sJt1vlH8MuimiufS5QlZOnaWYfgjte8mEUafP0uSCdkv3ohalsU/zTH9OAobjvmAWlOqipTVUmmZfcrF0SLJFTK0BbpXUCejzPe28nPtA@7mCmvPS6nvb/R3HltoL4jxaGHBa1C5C/p5c8EZYIBRLA4gSSgjZOTzRhllb6Iz30LGz5jpNmyj5Q@s1Z8DWteBJCDIXvs9s05cjUfhxMQe5uHXJ5W3u2cHBzB1IrbPN9dfbJQsHXbrZ5d/P2I9FDSWoo4NYR0HOY2SjFGyB4IPjRQjrHbM/sTA@TxmxHDqqtPoI8Z50HYbSUsmnMiwuRFedtNHEz07QDrYggJwLFqKX@eOTMkA2URTHWzNlT8hEd8HWYl4QBqz9KbUaxP8g7D18FdDXDdIMpBkMQqjC5wLuwua9@wDZSpKmxsK3INZPFvxMYdx0zQgVRfZz6J3Lb1J3jZ6MWJTRhyv1O1UEpBYTGMhlF1Fn0f2O4ozIhXAFD0Mvvws@Q0eP8oAdxTuzo/GlXEdyHigS6KeOlZGy0Y3JOSLnTJ00dOnuqZtgVp@RyJFY0@qk3VgEGM0ECp4gQna@CYBl3QckXSVZAH707IjvjCnYvAOhFOSHCvfgXPnNUdCKan4IfJdRaUQDEsHOWGq3eo6LJXlo45jociZINMP0YPg/4E0mQN/G3acAD2mlhEE8FGUJKhMK9i@ElHCW3XQYJxuxNQ0P32MwdyZHfNZN0ye3kzYvwZIIHtnqj58pLCHnewcAiCTo2LDHL/aJO2zD1unn2xHFsdzkn7rapgVcq1QS8UM3NzGhUtil6vOVvDFEQ7rmowKD6Go@Ik3bpc06mHLlNrKiyeRzeAcFf8jv0IKED3giUs/s9VqmrMKcpSpeUCGWjIWnLaOmARi6d29p3YrwgiRmZj75cmXIhSA3kF8ZttJ93wMBJvnJiMu0kosTikKHoYGx20yLj4yZN0lGWL2AoTzpE3KELwKZHyLC0SPoVOovhiayD4hQxGsJLY6jOMM4nTreEBaWlZvNfakmUQO1dif9TkmfcBaLZXD4wAfEkPTXd4Tb/0poNx7XLOZxfIr9YGLtotYGaslZHm89qQ1GIxAdPSx3YCjG04dT3yQSoegH12PZPxCWM/CkdRIKKEfqkGxiXfvtMxwOHhCLQrH6K3Q9og/qElXAVqIcniSSW5DZIF5FY/uKKVjOFktiux2nLINNKGwpETEbbEhvn7lXExQGTI0IAqGkd5ckM0m1YPnDnr43Q5Gv@LajyJQvx20dWRSAyTpArmTan2K8dgac9OHg4g0GtAVqAHRlCiyIk0bqsIa/UKyk7RrsuPomBi7lFry/fVoJlXWUlBRzLiydmC@jRx0JlJpTYYG1cFCi2vrhMq8DdfdvZsxihaaPLYW9nlfTylbLESUnyjREZ943tRPH/FJKvnLTyIcPfAFz7ilCIoIo8yK56qz8xzhhzYFH8Jg1DZ1oiDJtP0hqt9o6zPoEy8q1aEM@9fyx1EwhR1AKx9O8gSjmf3T4HO/uTfo@d1wEPqwT8OI7hOe8fBxSo/YYd3R4DaiG30ooW1kak/jZ44vw2HY8F2fS5aM0FzROBhmTTOF8Wha@cxhIkhzjkaA8aWVxN/DdIw0Xeb5elzISvqfkj1e0SndW/ZZcV5hPtFHAHKC20lZULAP6Zgckwzn09JMhsuHMhg4Xoqc8J17LPYSGL8EEtExTAJjhcyMWYLZCNyZ3Ytxoz1x2xSDcISBloL9AG@fibL02fXxemCYRV6hpcCWKG4WjKJ8ijLBOIT4ML2f3Gsv/mDsAYEfQL/4bB63zGMEmuI6KtpSxPsVGWUUcCHzwJDmaJqJYRYLu7AK9RJAm5M01GTy9D5qkOUPCEUyzN4MV@KIzMLGBy@eyzZhymlOHVxUlsWyQ3E7UASpjLOF@xk2@Jb9LA1@PMRlzRlOTHsSctZA@j5StYBKeBNqyrzWRJljKn97xKytPbbXUgQszzM5M278zdpKciEPlJDXVzzWGoxgMrZT1JOmHsvReDBcfiT17p075kZmm0frluN80xCYma0Mi@VKm0hbnuLjtGSl8UkxTZJiZGkGPITbV3rWbJ4m4qTcxPFWbk6/QYf7aBbbTelFRfd3m8c@Loo3aNGrFho9pAh3DFJa0t8bTWh48/4ZRMLk7VWTZowmThnNKT8aoFJk0lR6PIWI@yTuKXq0gXJYbxtoZ/bPvURNG8mpkKcqKRHkEumJgdvRaRPmpWEHjS8wTBxLuHqS0gLnxJ3SUV4xd4lBhjGBAaJUHORiPRRrcOPOSvER3Q7QyTbRWqiIMxE87ZgWDjrovyYYReWXyh1p8dCc5ooXJYY00ZBgV0G5HoKk/M3htdGcEJQZUsAQn0MK3aKZuenz41v1o22BfACBS1OytPQtuNgYR6wCNvDHTGpOUAaOq5IlEyMqORCaNDXAWIBdSrcX8HYVpb9wxByP1g1yGMEGgj9n8WdVlsBw3hsFTW0sMmlPMYsjyc2jzRG5HS4SMxS/I/nlUGRRlzauACBgjKF8uQgQMKwpYY@HAhR6x@S8BKKyj6BguYjDEj5SVNTYznNOOhJVZni@buQozMvx0oSRmwsEBIv5eWJEQGaZnyWGAgvdXFyMHC/mtyfOAQKx4n2mOHSF7JUkDXXPMQHpQuSCE88ojaJwC5KDKfH5upNI1PxNqS8LRmohnQr00Rg2csV06mYhkZqodm0tWTRREujhmLUmEoEUjomwnhV@7B@5ppghz7VNqLHJSEgZ0j4bL6yGXSbs27y/RGKbnLKVjKHgmZ7havvV5CtWEkHZHw7ALpbpyABjt/9wa5VlqsJE3hVAcemUs0uWN4Qksdq41GOzcKerIu3pAAVqTzvoiPenBweJsK@XU2VodBWM1guFAjLxpRn8XtlWoyopHOSTufOd614vP7z90@j9ZZ7m/iCgKwG21A46gC6BQRF5g1GXb4ZAHCAr5s5JR1bc6193OuYVDHhCiZ0H3cY5ZTQEQQtQqI1e3p@SAohAygX2F2wgtu8XoUffrc@CpoSijqGgNJoE39jq9AzIgx86aJ@tT6oIGE7MypoJ1i2nvPMFVxC82YQ6i8IXO19i82T7TdDrDVzxAe8ExkgBC3fpAgcHZoECZ8ETRvLuvY4oHq0rgpuwZ/gVYxaT1xGcWpjUPRMqLjzGxj8JutXJMGs3PtmwrECTV7GZqxif2hV213ZksPhHgGU@BLQflfvKH2ZbRKd0Zljq5QiOnwCjZ0V37t4nkcUhnZik2bdzI1Hno@tRsAZoukOygIplT91LLbknuyaufT4pdpCGBYYhccKYK48rga5mf9y0eDPudB43K9I1ANyx3zUj8k0oPzYh0hkAjUA5/ICeGEX7X3IwrA9SAUVYwMHLOmbnHSzQxAKW9aRV/u02W6lUxNJwdVVUKrvwkMuJym5F7OOH3V2xD@@7@P60vLa@XuI5d9/5Ah931cc7sQswSMO52vo82odXSCuj3xhaa2MXL@XLS25pqVne3ilF@UZlF9364ekf//rv//i3/8hX5Mt/4csuvTQ@6Uye5@WXWl@Wnt6V8L2xf7G8dNlYGl4sd0vIZf@kqOGD2jjnx@aj3ujSyvAqYHwlO1K1z6boM7KoUBf8XfmjX2F22RKZVpTPyK8R3xxFc2ymFRjfA/SjvIQtvLp0IL2VByQyAHSK6njonVaABniw3gAlARe0A@XyfLaiFPcYDkZn0KcqGRmJh2TWmwB9WuJICuiLCytWLuxHQR814Dck83LzLMuH33DclPyb//Q26u4OJmLlPCtWCmLFFSu2TT/FjZfw1VnKh@idy9lgO2DbLqTERwtoZiiikAQ92j/QXTspclvWEl3Zg5BUmArKzF5wrt79kbMMX7gWda0FvD9TsIqEDpmwSObLUv8OuuUL5LizE642JCg05S6GKjNOVHT/ogjkR2wIENd8xQTZGkCVeNJHHsn4lFdfZF9bdJsQAUaynrw@oHGPH2AtWupLm@fEXgqvOSLzef6Ka2OJnaEJbUzh@mME6ECFt5MF8iRczixbbOVttJKayV7YZvsk87GtwzQYK9t0LvRXYTABW3ObhFvqS78WacjNxyvCDvXxilGVnbb9FpZR5Oq6Nw6H0l2BascB9UXXdscjCXuUADEcjtm/NTvCSFGgIkWluoUvy5qK9gCbziOhL13ToYMdj0@ODCLkP2VhbH9NjW0nT14iih2YBwgpbcrX8cNeJKOujIjYXX90ibcD@h26UG3M52akz8MbU1MYDzoaaY8gk8l5PJ6hKZnhyO9e@a7IHA1OR/60BssWSD7jludACzEEEyKBg09WPa95CmFukewSoohuClkO4eUFvam8Ho371tY@J9ilaijIsCs4CBLsRJQMvib6KkXHmKu/oxNMlGcmb30aKadYmnnR0khCsk23GRpmM0PHUjWYY0cPHNtiVPXIVLwgC13jQntFB78wk/cwRoCs25ZegNIVYeMl1o@rUzfo@4nFadizlKN/viR4XcTxTFdRsjWSpS5BLcY33iFWIEd@SkaB4LVJhTOyFrLZhfNIXueWMdcRCvKtbfHzvgj1BXR0gRl5hoizfsiTZWqFiu/A8ESNLP8BQqfndwG/6a0/RVY8z2RfLeadxqfz/sVK9rz/9fx3hzCRU7JaZXMiIw@z1YwlxwqsjHk38aqs0iIVavC8n8xw3hfsw2KQABDJZxuf8hdf84DQeQavlz/PMEESXYaY5B@uL4/g8zNoZpJY5DPWgrPiqM7Pvio6AtZW@sU@5A8O/wIWalNJanrY54w6AIr8dH@7ZpeTKL@5Vni@VnwOO6FuMMmNgmtcb3PR9WUwAVEiwu0sLD3nvye4IUGIu0nkl@DjBNrJ15qw70kknZTkFCqHOdVjabaCMh7zBOQHKlO4VHRxcXQeHw8fccPvCmA5lZdiQbHpoMF9WVw/o8EV1uNHOK@lvUOYI9HKgG1ESIWaQ8jq8pX7ONRRw2WZ/Jw8sYexWwkIdG8@Y6wW/UE/J4U1x1suoRCNXjO9zcJmIT1GZ4ZoYoQuSWFqeVEUd169@Pt/Hv@WGWd21vIfRvA7zvyW2djM8CM8wNsz9XaT2clsY7aNu8w0D3tgeHzx9/@G8jt/AjiYMt2GPzvrCtbGNLOTK1ORr5mdDXgorq1Bvf/zt79BG5Z4x4Z3sS41XUGIlRRF9vw@8S6kixq2krely/G0Qo5ZCIMtDGFvDi9oGDVZ2yyQmi4jrSpuAhn5StmjyCWeDLPGZCrEmgxlTwGSERcoYwU5BqlMKDrCsN1QZhvIvDGa4pcn3kYEO4BfpDmHrlKbbjyJ0GRoibdF0IFZrhH28/ywU3hla/OOLVvZlJSUCIlbOznXbj4r/S8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/cbmo5)

This answer works in [online js interpreter](https://codepen.io/nelmvn/full/xxZdzGo), it doesn't work in [vbs interpreter](https://github.com/NELMVN/Tetr4phobi4).

Code with comments:

```
4OUR    +4    4
fuor    *4    16
fuor    *4    64
FOU4    -4    60
FOU4    -4    56
FOU4    -4    52
fuor    *4    208   |
FOU4    -4    204   | -1
four    /4    51    |
4444    prn
fuor    *4    204   |
FOU4    -4    200   | -2
FOU4    -4    196   |
four    /4    49    |
4444    prn
4OUR    +4    53
4OUR    +4    57
4444    prn
```

Code in polyglot:

```
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
```

`four`/`fuor` are on the same line to simplify fixing LMBM (note: js interpreter doesn't require `$$$$` delimiter).
See also: [hello world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203732).

Answer (score 2):

## 321. [*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), 14640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1 1 v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v   >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9 @,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMn>MnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001 1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X 
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
Yo::=~147
::=  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa










































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::geEx Cr Uithary,85"3.c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0/a4on;k: $/op>s}e}equ+4[0]!!tfc;""[ ]5:ore>80C0 4?4在ｕ
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ5L3U7W62SPbtK4G46AJQAKoJVKGrABJoNjskza7Wsr2zHo3skB/jK2vWs/J6IsY7sbOWd@yZCHs/Tjjmk39A@7Gx4diw/oH2nJNZhQIJgN3yOGJjY4tEVT5Pnjx58uTJd8vw@j/7WQQf9tQZzHoDZ8zGpjdmHde6MF2VPZix@4bl5fSMJGGoXbc3GZr22CtLEaYx5o0Nd8wGht2bGD2TRcBVZ3N71xqMTTfJPNNkLXPgXIJ/hjHbvGSHdtvqACQ2ds5N23ptuuCXZeyhOXgzfDNmbWc4NOyOx0auZY/JN8fYUwMs3Un7nBktb@wa7bHl2OCVZ@yZPTCGrY7BKPjINXmkAgNQ7XOKs@hTZOyx43ompOC0Tc9z0LEEjoZrOY92n3x8I7yWZh8bgNRoYE5vJK9p7Lllup2bMXT22enBwU3XDPtUcWx2cBslLct2J2PncHwTfo7t9kzbYLpaUvWbnnkg5tgcFNPF9IIX@B1YLpSmIUqtPC8ZezJsmS4QXxThpTXuqxDh1OEEZ449mDFzCsAAxy4EM8fMwtJiuXQaQ8L/idl27M4cPDiZAAfgmsPReMYUZjuCB8DLcZk3Mtqm0jEH1tAamx02sAA7pyuw8RgUODs3Z5eOCwWvcFYkRLyR2ba6FkYROfAkZLaHZmvSY85kPJoAeh7rWJ7RGkCw1ox1zK4xGYyTrAV@QDxyv@ybtkDJsnuYj@dzF4RgQxXg2G9qQBtrMGCAzjmig0l7bBs9LtEdg7ZMwtLsIKj9ObkAkjHw/NwvJryQDMZ76jo91xgCo3ZMosFnh0@Z13ZcsMEPw/JasA5M2xiz7W0W3X/yMMpqARlVtyUFJK2yK8ZYxPdkF8ZgYnpsaMwgbXsMlYs5VH5@DAmCs@hGtMyimQzT0yybZVmobEWm59IMqkQJDFBr9YwGvzzTiyyrAd/noklMp@saPWtgcig9Z9BFQAXkWD3HdHinsyyjFaNJHqJN6RRYpsjyBVbIsQK8S6ykQ0IINcu0Ug5@efgBlBJgocEvk@WpBayBLAXZYHusawytwYxDH40QfJvlNFYAiICqBpD1IkAo6Qhh8QnDG/eBuH3jAkAqA@scRYYZSA0ssRR8UltbKRJbKB95kl7fHAwwVSAWkClXZAVINQ8Zz0LKQEu9qPuZ7/Up@4RXIQ0/wLEAOS4CidNArTSSqwA/sIMo0kHm6CBgdJAZugbuOpgzCBXC5cEvD@WVz/rQ9Q7RFiQsxNWQmChUNKQBRINCYBkoijzLQhFnsIhzGQZ4AgKFPAO5UtRYMcuKBQbkKqUZkF4DZLD8NZBnGiChITAoVg3KVQNENGAYDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9dLc/YC3PQcZDKXIb7T81B4BfADYumAqw7cogO2ehH8MW4RCFdEtiz4hDAGo76BtIASQGYGVgOC5AAngg3hwawXMpylKHTLHFtt6VqCmsVbwbDU8SUISgGQKMxg2IgCA865JxZIwTgIpUWBNfHMAXARyJG2AWZkW6jxKD18ONZYRVkLTZXpXGBjSiJgIRmPxETLxZYUZFbHdF2GYaHB9ZIkULxJyzNfTbC9nePVBQllgnDtGtYgQICqjjGmtgC@UQ/Smy2i3XWdIdWvIQqMgeOMVoheEE@XCOgT59Kcoz6XXsZoNACZDu4mEGJiDACZS4N0AlIZwqlyhCASxmv3LQBISYFstVyzTbQXWYfYGZDCiyiWmV67l0EoD0JNQ4aNHBCsHsaxJ4NBGZo8s80ytVTHvEihC28@FpsNxMFvUKBNFCBaBrTn1KAiFgGke7pKTdWpX7KeM1zMGhcvh0HW@xY2A4NLYwal1wXJYk6NIWgdDJt2GxrvIXAML0EsCY83Poes49jRcQDl0oUmFjId5ARADogmY2togk7mQBQs8SwhjcKNMGvNgJWJWlmVVDKOyQ1CqdJNQnGHbMiBVxZo3DqTNlIN07Zs4iBoFDxqsWoAlyueKhqgyrmm0eHBUMNAjEI6ErR4JhBdqANtAoRaiml7oPF4KrNQNQSG7zld4DFqpkHdgKjzdNqUd8x54DRV26pElEa@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@L7Zf0HSORo4LNYMLnRlKMl5kIe5yeF8lFjQRceg7L7ao0FJEsZ0fj3m/azSAvhBVMaypoE8aIClAiPFeAMg8h6cYQphqPcES@F2SxOfMBE2obZuokhrujAOB7EGrDAnNmOW6IAYvsG3gTY/fhqjEp9AUGJ0OSlYkB9X7m4mryNF7k5Y1vdnVaKOj@tKTLgyXdbGX4YKuAZUoFu160XiF3ClmyEtOOaNxiqLytwwBKZAKRR7rQscFGoIDEDQnM7sdkxeqmJxk8mTcLcpxMGBErpqxrxqj8U3sXoIbMs3wHOo12SqsB622osBbQTfCBD1SKnoYLqgXUAlByy6VOi2DvQHp4TJlukexUS2kr6Zmg7RMuxOkJQiBuITzq/IkPLdNBiXUqmEOMDjlnBqJBQK@JyUoogwOqZRoP9GBlDzuR@oMd5zYNETAYlwDibOrQEWHBiBGyFigc1hta9wUWsq9e76@slGtArOBEgVisxMPK/f@WIoKkhoCq6SEiETUsXMyxroRi0N@MfA1xwa0JeDUao1djfsu1DiyX0sQCMgq2cjJPmFFOT@xziedmwVtoyMGkrHWga5ktcdyRYLGn9eG6jqqRheoCsp/FKmKzIvxCfQt5iVXLFBZBHNND7XeqkAlVMIxxEDw6lIS8ajCbc7Qe7P2QKgE3ASVnUujFqB/LnrrgSBKCp3Ar7S3aioHgtWBw2FPd08/qYq6yD1TLcsuLzgMnLYxIOdNDC77cR8dPjjePf56cwmMgdUq33RIWdliHpvayVTp2ZNUVtXLm2EYc8APm@thY8TFMLIkvJniTEOq0qwNjcvUJ@fR8ac3SQKaEJKDUgAz/m6oNDwMKF1Sy/D6Nxph1kskIMkgih@WKYfMhxkYEHX0N3x8nk5ev8bCu4nUSLgjZoOJwQH4jqlD24@noucNBcz3anV5i0hxQQu1bBwDnZvCIX18Pkat@SYypEqHWObjo4P94yqB7RveuTkYKBQk5Y1BlzLcjgo8P5h0TGlZGBB/YGqzhDpHHPVpwnUpgdvtBQLPy5atgA8AsIujOkwZDP2seX3Afe9m3shVaQccQHaCcFOvDOtD7Q9FNIQHNnFt7Okua0XJY95YBU5LW6zAd7HZaudyZiFbCjdb7XmanTDQISnFluPrjS54nXsKuqhzLVKo1QL9k0e3EPdIiYSugOJj5g2YSml5Awl7L4rFol5qD3pozsBUn5PEk5kcT6Wi/uCn2vaozxkKvz@1xrF0nH@1OISF1Hd3D/WHfmAxUEcDGNRpwC44tkxuFycb2h7wiO0MnJ7DtiAO1w79BEFtWpnN3Z5j3yohAx0xqxGcvQD5i@M1xgjaGus1dRwpVri7ymc@DNu7BCmt5TNIJKIQgUpRePWlcWEAueb5Pjn8xj40IlounQ7MaXqABKE4RC40tUOu5MAUSEgV@CzNYDCTcau2@x5KaCoBMy0EXRBxd@691JEkpppaGn4pSl91blH8pTO7wVrgwlkLDCGSHT55@ujwyf7j3c/Pxnout2DPpkt5IByk1wJdSO1zumFt3eJVE7OF4CJQN1ysXiAFJtBB8YfEJ54LglvFICpHYAXX8Dmg2Fedvh314jczc4m@yku7zVnoMVY@HlREhI52Z4CdEZdPnWF7jvzTH49HXjmVglren7RU6LSmXradgdFLUTxoGAaDlIZdl8MjHNfwlsUAZLyZyWPwMS1QHWY0cGgMhg50Xmg6DkUDi3HwNFg1sHp96AvjnJ3pxtWAgyk3qQ70EKCvnAryRgKYbEBb8fXLSeas/RVNL3K@1tJ6NiX7wRaqP4Td6JrQdYpBawWkiN@wsrN7Z/fYDKQ0QroJJMLULTFtg23BgIEiSYOl2M/3iUPSAodJUVYQjV5NcBAXpFQql84WtHwuBd0y6KaBzqrgUJsyNMbtvjJ2FICnOF0aNwhxYddrG3ZX3RIGH1nQ@z6CrGbqX5yd2Q1Q0M/uEW44GVafNepaI15ht6NsifDxCnDvQvaQd30H4F0yAmvSl62QZx3jtjjrGFS7Oiw1Ho5Em6OM2ONdUKReOyCvO2a47mGEVNgztbUQNoWB36aWDAgNMKqEL6RUCioUtLTAeinESwGlF9VD4ByQW6EIbD6awfPBp6BDcgQ73cj3lhP1aKwe9RocJPVGQEQaY26jlPZwfHAMrWPA@SiloXBRSLNLM4rD54bHBykhkph49ONDXy2AQIPxwUC0HUy4AhNQLOqeg@QAvsLR0v58lBE7/cBpkCDhhIMPoEHYNGnQAzkDkXlGdnlGeErkspilc9u5tBFay2RFpWWN@Ri/M3FxQs/qhPMGwTM6DwPQKHMhuU4zfy2zzUdZeWTKBXQCDTY0hw4OJYB2RaLApCwYfNYQ@4IeDlRDtUorOHEC8BV2fw@kWNvk40XKEDtRwFL7LDp2U7vKN1KG8hq4eY1uhZnfDU9iU6Gf@gSgkchgFptGScQIKGknzpACPafxFvR84Ku70mg27kOOgcNko@qMTPtmn4/3CGPxCs21RqMg8C07dhXd2NiIlqO1aBJMO2DaRtMOmhJg2iGTQiYMp6KJYiTJhL51ioFujeh13Yc8jTeQB6aoOby2RjGjXi5nGkmjromvjt84FAVQHkIr@AE40Xi1isZ4XK5d4lQN6O@hvO8h75y0XWskSPBVUAi4XdAgQ0SA7j1q865Zwb7peooMqy50Gk1UMWNu9KyePmucXZ11EmfX0STGjleMKvQPQXiNY0O15zqTEShu9WxZAdkWr2fKjUqrGk1Ht2KxojKAhIx4/KNiPGFwWseiJvBU7OwsCiQV1Km3@y7Bmyb1eDwgFODRtaCXMRjEoupVEdJvxRvxRBTixqNJEMvVaBTo0kYieJRpHBHgTHRgTYGUUDGhiQvPKZCApDkprK7fMEf9mRsOEIy6gZaNI@jzCXmoDCTFw1LyNY8fVugWevq@3svDgXKLg3eoL41mXLpLHNOz1MLiEL/dvVC6Q2dspD5TodOkhprL6EY0pSjQEpIPh0TZfmx5WIUN23QmXnikcekAKKYOrqf9CQhLf@VMErjKGklmu@@w6OZ9gM6CaR5sSnDGSuHzXj6ATluFHwpR1EpwsgS0C1pSYoFcxOUmfFRGIyS46PHH5nP50Ss1SK1CcVgaE7J6tuOaCpAEYki0AISWC0k1JlaVHNLI1615CeFLTRp2vC0TJOLBwDGItlxch@aDRsNQfOifQ5RjsyMNQH50QTyqvCxcs5Pakmhy1nH70EJAblAS60FpDYVHyvFGHXU8hahSDBvcsCfv3YHSeck6uq7n27lu2fdDrgBi96GQsFdqQxfX91I08IyLQt7nw0J@H/3J0cN9PnZCjS02rziO1hw6nQnolaLfdGzavSTbB36ybGdoARn8@K/PB8eOM@a9fLCsGpnhnWZrOBkYNOZzc1hmbby203IGNBS0Luo8/MT1jIHBB6F8393PHoOu/@z0pKqWQ4FSxsVwbdo4Drk8WU7Pw/CcI02z@tNDHmdMeTMnY7vlL0hDMSM88ugxEcvRoIx89wK6@1UK51CEexHdh7gUDXRlMYpA1sBRBCxRQFyehqt6hOOVlr5G95V9sCCcRuG44jjH9krTyf1i3O0uOGfI@VxB0TSYO2fJmS9TW@gjhlHK8UC4Zm0hTBhQnsIES9duhhPCK1hi0DcH/gziMSgmOEsGbfsA1Sfom6AmztePmaBIj3AyhCQ0TrGxNuia3q1hC6hTI4WHliIbVE@gDUuh5iJtppgY4q5QTbEdMTXpcenpQNeeRk@2a3zCGrtOLu@1pfjg@2YTQGzXKv5qolXBMKVoNAhGUAk3iEHZpGn7W1kNFmF4NKYuUZSK5KWg1zDV08rZtLDfSHlEhC6Tz86mH6X1z6Hzgeu@Nu@lemYFk1tJLbLzceh2H8QGS0wXSQblMLG7zqCj8EkvKH/Gu0tYEGKpQbDyjAQ@uFiuv@jMwkUsYnEgiMvQerVbcG8UXe12gNAKtwAQ1IYr9uY8efGG1aEFu1C90cAaN9i1Onaafcz8eOLaN9fCcZXSdY2ZJ4mVKlW2e/zxZ/V0g0OQhgZOZBV5aU39pZSgB4PegytWwYTrbcbWmBp2WlhgYX41FZCa0pwHoA8weAIVFiQkcoSovzHfzPPSNaHjGTMRc282TDIzfq12B8Z4bNqct/hs4mpy82kfkUyVkt8RcwhllqaJFlA0LfQDFCvs5PTh/vGxChzqxaL7OCFThmpntPugb6zKtE/JcObL7KNOlH2EceLYC5egSkFnoiniA/NWgLmhOwGpoyjomW4MHOM4l9IGZ5q@oohc4RIEwlVT7THRKAAWM@OQJwJWXor/M5v3nASeZRZlCaIkkDt2rwy0teLqxLZeqR60G6SGQpAo73vSMtnqZozE16YWJ/5xrSHOBUOXibRAyEO9zjZAulFomVXfsi/qaaXUSGyyRqPCZ/ghIur0tOxWLOE0BD35dBgJSIHzoeiVdW8s5PVToJFbjMXx04BnJcG3gKw7ac1u11J5U5fjAbLKa3DgnvJNJJcsNOUo@kubSITQSqjFFU2L66VC2XpGnewbC8QhOz4CQX5wGjLGc8k2qkyLx33MOKDnhotd5zJ76nie1RrQCtbuwOIrwYLGuiwIIyD5lAknV8GKQXTD@gz1DAtjvmyZLwYWlCB/amigJ4U5I4dYnF0hMYmUOlKRvXmDDjLb1BmxgYyrhjl9r/0@LcjHRw4g@0isgg7rHCQ0xPIUFB1nkux33hbnf9GHdwxSFzd0XuVCDsfjOqdlnzs0ixSYmmlVy6GeGcQeng9ux@xaXp9eC0EDHHhYfRV23rDVpdeSADSZIqbpyYGG6YWGDcVppI7pQyP2S1JeXJqykGzL7E7sHs1popkpr@4IqZSKFLjbalmrggIRcLWZ/10SDGQl1jxdzaqaX3twgAeaRZCfvE80z/rNVU1sge7QSI0hlvj@5292gP63S6cP7RWOZwaGJmgKWFJKd2VhiahoodfyguXD7pOBZRBhyHQXyLbhQpaMQWBYDpqm9hUF9I0hTlSIEgfexBfoomvYjGPO5xn97/JElk3V2SC326vC3ljlxZOiSSXoLnaICFznskyKREKWF4I55RM7oY47Cty7kfKXYjFiZl7u/cl4wt@gDt9ZiNYIf@vqpgiZzhktzYQOqdGyzDVF7hrnk46jjM57gVqcXxJ2nnuaWVZAKxGTzE00Ls8@z6Br9aC597@rgs3b19Qlfe7iCs@eeCOlRX37DrdRRRiuScEd8PeqIJbYrRQYVlPNGtDrPTlRQAdGEWssUriCVQkRzbpB5oHRmqEq1P9wLgvWK4DEqbYTiXRmxYT1aLQ6PvZPKX6ptDz2VG1zeiwbeUjxVbIKH5ujDIt1s3eUKjRX1tAYKHonZFwpzJctd7gVNJgppTjmBc4TXSwtuTn1sUFqTwaGOzetYfE5Hv7kxKpxbtFsiLrcdgaWhxV6sEpq@mvu5mnhOmV6hdZVWMso2YGOKLbjSmBaLgWc9hjXoq5gq/eQaXwNKK60DfGJ6qwiVtu5xN9KDaIPnWH@Xt6ovV6K1XvIJ2XQHhjQlK9sERZGHXFU8w5evbQ8k17LCXu@FNFxe7DUfbEW@OOJ4fHBuzjbswaOx07ovY5APReowN/LeTpMS8uwFRplD5vXiCF/8cS8QI1Bzxnki72UAa@VpT5xuyj6xfd9hVwgpDTtDiHla0COrYnvStF@nnLP7yog2v/l4sLZkHFNK7tMUolJndW5g74Bzgguz9lBukgx1RQfQ1yRMM7lXBoz//tztB6rSOu3HqMZadSg4GGEUhEMY5dr2T9Patn1qXXeTyjdAlu4KxOhwj0fmNBe0ftWkTI9rX1gDC2dfn8R1R1MzIm5tK9x1Hpp4lbiNf2M90cqLbKxKaYAcNYB97wEoV6LzuF7YY1NNdrWChMDeu3m3drMolAbgQI@wt7zUzA8RcPtGD17Mloo1YUOmn28nmT9kV@lnc4CdujzoXKoeIeytKCieyb91naaeCcPV55Vs@l0WugwoamcBcu6zlQmiPvS4u@FhMllnvI8LE7fuSHj8jSILOG1jStFkL6qb0@BS6WUbdnmeIbv95SmLccZfEhJgVDtWKiNgXJJa3jXldgtdUfsTmHz0QsPxzxa3VXjFry1Ed1LoA/2m9cVeniu6b1KU8HZ1CHOdC1a14/ghGau7koFt3TjsBBf1TtYrUuKARFNLaqFtbWOa6hOyxwY/DPNZ9fBK6mZtfAWhYaYBcZZYz5XPJ/jj9wQSqMZEMvqQEelbw5Nsq5R9I3Oy4nnf1YGmjr4W@U9Nc12arpvtlcFGFkgF2x8L0xOh5SlsWNDF2uMCwixqzLAJarCdZUE9qcTlxL5cGj0TH5OxTpJOR@zwGU6vGc3Ny4fvSjzpTltiDYfYV7NElCpzs2Z53@XAnw8a0O5ToZ3j7jdqPxtHAZ9j9q@am3s7SbW7jt9u2/2@YL0wLaqcgA/jvm5IutQB6x7fVwjNxotrJ0P03PgDAbvQ08UjVxQOk53KU77uKsWt4R9ENyZ0QIP8blz/M4Yc9mBhpW1pm9OoF3ynLEzMhWyrQo6wLEe/l4lQ/3Z7593EGltVx8o4n9/Xvh39i17hjMejejTHA0mHr0oqkKboe/Sm7p8zQuttnTcnvraGbZU4aiKBTE06b5cxLSscbuPm9A5Z5s9p9XuW3ch3TKNsW2dp/xRH259r74rUsZiykN0VgcWkNedqcgv1bD/CX4OVxW6GEDizVpgWKOvLBuko/3eysg4b3t8QBRNrIxjwqHayHeFl2k7ffnVxBrPgYYWSQUjvHxmAg2rcBfLMlZqVrT5Yi6GxXKNlVxKSjoq5IqZBoVHWzm@tLCALlTFMhn@WoVQOJeEUWjBy4eQWywqogFCKzR0C@4L/LWwGmppI2f3Jz3vtsDkI/YdUNHwtXrYghZJh0atoc0ybPFZRWZ9kMLdk/Btgs41MddOq@TWzqtQOG2gGI4FnyZ8oOgmK8fQBtbI42@mdFfOxolFUtAXvzllyGkzW96ZFgXTMbt8FgRNd6mIQ4fmaUEHUdo4p4@D6CjMueLFBZft9ECoKwM2D@yHXaW2LF1/tLz4gzZT@fyJ2TNwEfcja4yrQJdwBbHssnVLd8L@2sTwrK9NIGermA2PguAzkW74zAC0LYH32OhZ7U8WCiJAUhBYLCHlnwX2R6fbZXHZtzxcQxUY1gxMIctxJkaua0K/YUnIm0P3wSkY8wrE91cuDb1seN0ZzXAb2oxM60bWrTGNsorvqq7jqtVla5G4nAxHE098luNAq7TCo9DDc3L3Li0ArrwC0cr6xmC8fKQ6NOQKWphoFOfGVdr4N6yB02PfKKYZKG2ghKFyvoRxHkDz/BSXBrn2Ek6ktN9z5hMHOhSXZ@wVlK2ZYYplW@P1oznjMS4T8r@YGd5y4NaH1CN8q/c/FIJyupwij@7W9ed7nu9o34HzTpyJ2zbRGBxkEu4WiFTNPX9ZM24VcfAglstwL23t7A00h449GSvuxF7bKuTXtgplNi3mQ2zAYl/bf/wsHuYGWgZ@lxZqQudv4g1mc9PKNQM3mMyyQRFbLUcXQ/t9iYf83KVjWoN8R5xdPByqTeL6obOsv/N05prj9@4wgfCfDB@abZw5vDPtJ85jx3agNRqBoBwem/wwgYW1HssjYrRHuF0e6NO5M5kTAruiEeLahjEyW1C@g7npfdoiDvihMTZWNEU0Nkj9v8B0J69Yg5bpvqRBv5B5VZd2EaFPzCn1LVYzDK@Dyrjd5ioxjsct1JGFGRtv5Dg2f5O0TcNHe7xeqkBTQK/3nytXcYX/wrjA0v7ZYlaPLvhCEbPDT7tYlVfXbDkD/l6zLMm2@LIAw7VML/UID08gt3yWKaB9eWtlSGGtDJl3jUCTvTA8mqdf3tWYg9SmH7AKqG@4bQdnwoRhzQKd0IkHd4jpYNMAXzvQAsJPQWIZ7Yk4e/EutAbD1pBeKzsModI8Nlu43ahFx4SMjentwuQjQ@KMhNCiruBkAV9cYaXOs9hT6I3E7262FvpRi1S1RvQiSb1yupzW6yi2ZbZfGzhq5hC95mPTC/6Q59QTMq4Yqw5VIxpFThm0hX5pTVpcvQYKzcBUxn0X@vyp8brhbf/8liXzIZOhiZPMi7MwK1VXx@tTZp3l8@mBcHVNRZwdCLIkOEeQ64fK7krNE8HD/9GDr6agEW7ms/6ZJiC67p7BB@Qnri0@78OBTx1v3LWmR4A37jtYJU4wWzmIAh9eM9C0tSoTUHr2ZMBHH3qhpVfDDnXHFDrDVlEGJK7HpmLaFwqdMDe9nSOH7yZL7eJhqGOzo4gDFnCmQXnkbywLgonvkgnUsGzE9Z5aihN2ms@KFaDLiHvpSwbQt5yxMvLomxp5Tw8fHZ2qI09b2j7t9nE/xi09buHEBr2YDg1JvTTc0HwnX5HWsbxx6sGJpuw9OlQxwAp68xkNBT44M7fwWTnuKY4eNVLGyl4Q@prj5QriJ6ePHyXmez9ZbK/vOkMzHvbeOzlJ4t6Wr54s9Q7HPoDa0XWmK6Mf7mtafAn7PrNpdnCV9FyS0ipIpyb0RoEZP@EHvtypXLWdkdk5nY3Mz6DxRAnuvWfy@ZWZfGJcWD2shay0klBUUVlJzWfjocXZ0Nk23eC7qjzPrRFKyzZ9UvyzcjkKag6ZlJtZrj2sm/G/qcWwtFiJ8GGRtPRtbh1bCtSMXh9NKcP7hyKmadoqOp8YXShXlltZWIsBls0PD5yL95hKNkXnRQmclDFwlWLduZS8oAxBdKfwhcPzwhGMrZXLYNYBCJzzSyv8pWnPDFuhuax16kUZYuOitrVBvmG@x4RUsMLnAg@EXjrHF6yqZ7E2GeN3JHzqhqLs7T04vCvCsaDl@lAfP3nGnhoenm6yPmAYY/M9MJ5rRi8VHLfCo/VWTqd2XAClr4XXGy2vz2V2Yrgdx55N756Eo82t2LTTYcUBLLRRIHNgTa1lbVWbj2s9Xb7M6K60@T4OZ7agB4dPvRGA3n3nn2taOk1nGuFXS3PrHSXjV3AWQ5Mxw4Pywl6nh4FoaKPeooJDfGlv9JE5xeUofDR4Wad@afuWX9P2FeKrm5N1fsU1ftk16d3yQ0eWUdPaGoC5NX4spwbej5zBZd9R9wzX9N6zTEKorctSaU2WSiE5/bqYxuFQmmIU5tXKPu5jEJ@lfHtqjt3sqO@0rOwdudnt4omW7DEeyH5nJcMNZbT4peeIPSHcfhsHvt3reGKHDyD2kuIICb5Lk@@b81T/lOhYzE4k4vHFiwjCuwT5/jg8po5vbYOwb96wDbGDDTyCTX1i3xyeZgXqtIm7TSUCgdsZY3a1quVKbAevAyhDYxmnFNGJzgzy06qzzSuxHa1c1q5xS55clpnYLhgcAcqPsQS4eAAf5Ikp5xrbHIPPpr@ZjdFB7OwNIwUcWnwtlwabmgrvLq6IXX6A0ubV08On@yenu6fPTurpxrUcF3tZOW62Dan5u5w/ynRkyLsgG1Rsfqgt7YYdQHJ0SDwq7p6fLwY5u5G16kLW5pmSdzDO5pVtp1K0qTOlXAN@isxTI19opdGJw/ZzTOUj9uSW@V7IAZFU3uSgZUoTyqzM0ssSHhnAkJu28L95TQX5skwGfXnC4hxSYOGe43REip7J7n78FA92Dx89O95nPoJzprm0OuN@tZTjx9Ri46eYUE5di9aHVFlURIlCWVWr0YMoECaqRlmZttLSEbHA5xDMpw5uwhWxt1hsk@ADBaNBoaT@8zdT11EVlzrGIWzURyrKBOUxADvF7XF//uMOP0LdPxTDv4/FHZKkp8MHJLH1dcXGV6QoVczR6ltZ6Mhy2uManJU@v@lGohP0gSsv6TyrG2cdxen4EX7FjjiKyk@IGMQ/dhnHzPBYKejwX1i4wZXj0MVTnhZZGafZ6WQzle3ilTPA88ygY/wB9Yk95iepiHMXIsBHaiBQkmyTkOWH/suhgNHtDWDlltmzbObZ0BExx2X2EvgMx6XKfJe1otSit6L4oPldQ0p/PByEAt46FspLnY1T7371u6lehYF5mn4Atl8Wti6Yf4Wbv0hhWd8@OmqefhgJPO5NYM0TD2iO9A7drmPz3exzYuEJV76kZNYQiuaCKI3BeQr8rYCAncOJ1T@DggIWg1ISu9h5eqbbiOF5c@VUCtkIGzKVVu6aU76M5sa5c/lcPqulAEnlwgdIB0X3cIsgBxiPl4HxpQtrVH3RAvba3mYy6rVmNV/hpZnatL/IyC8CRDchrHTZR@TqDOJAlHkM8KuJaNCcJLQ4RkV5FNWiKIo6DrQz5I/tEdptQQiZxYBYnEYmnjw8xWuWxu7MPz@xhVcXhS4R2BSAFA1aGTLFZUlsvH7ijIFlFrac843XuIyMt2l4MJnHrxGjYwuRB9XbtWm@X9C/rUDULxXrPQeVSd9sHsNlKz9HECcIoiwvY9n6F@xsfGY3Upw3GbDpDwXLhpnZBvMvpXoreJbne/f2oXWxm0fOIbHY/RPbQQX@ADLDYnpKz6S0fHyepWx2aZZEjkQykB08SuMNJAeiCcRE27ReOiNvd2//8KtHT09uHcxGIaM3g4Ekr20nzhQ1WW8Ehmg4W4tF8uAgdfL4wYFfEHOk8yEJDNqLyIm2LifzfjmCnK/zvpm1ZRjezN1qjJ/zzaA38c3o61CjSLfw0NIfkC6ttVQOaMfEzcT14jJq5XLrUJrDS4VA7/HtbrdQjcWvruuN7dqZHYne5oQlFeGLiLqFlQBMZ97WZgqZ/XbmMGPBdX@neEmRF66LmeV1Ud7M4PlAuOF27JzPT0YSDiGPUH79ZEBESmrKD7qy9h1xrXt@fpfOryPkJwmFz08JIZxPr6N4CNSpf7MhSpH56YPi4L0@9I4HVkvyz63hB/D554QFZ@/xM2dicUmcYc8Tjom7DqflqUoLK2JxlHYEK8nWneXnw4tLUKFRX3s6gT7LU2fEzzSmCbSHpm86dkD8PpzwmXiTfXUyhHBd@hybNJgJkluByEDJaIAq159ASoij/KYJPCwR0qvjgX4i4@qwk4tN42rfnHasHsj2WDwJEu0jTWuw4Lg/zDQd72dHZSqzeSmsrYof4ybGMNk/6MzH6RwBo26olt0xp7HoZTRebkD66B69fH4RjcvLeInOnhSHMXZuHkIZoF/Q1ksSYyxqp3/C4zJpUSrdlhLgdhMwPz3Jv1ClVFL7nkT3YlVRFz8Zu4/ACGpErDs0Riw2sfkJUyoja@wsZifpSB6lxg@ps1kiQV0k@JCHyihml0y8/Y4Z9ozFUlVgAnT17A5@XlsjVtdUtQFmSiTONvGioz3QuPC0lrgEvVqIUiawVWQh6DgARrySqJzBIQ76S3iIjkvndC3xpntfaMzHQZpQrlntHgvdV7WoOcqlUlkU6KJULDHgvtviUE0B2FtyztflgbriNAigGXRoVSkyF@S3JV6E0o1wRD4Rx0gAOpHQwZL@6RIMYM2PfWz3XfzF9m2oK3ggTvnZ6UGzGE/JLDiOoudaHRyT5GcjB502cZsFVNPUQtBohffRPsZoeM5Yk593gcdgHVCFkW@I1EiYDDdvcJ3zpqat5XoRUZQChMxiAyD27DR9cHignj87vMRvubD/2c/wjlg5trmTzzQHF4loLl2Bl1bJsRz7aPNMUTbrmpZNV@9vGsb41ZnMjFR26@GF2e@2DnupM1lmGZZNpbaiB1tPLT3/xavpdUYrvjofafm6@mrakIvV5Hljyp4@/fxt821cnl7M5LMYY4UIY3tHb2Qti53VSLnASgx/C89rfNEVjkufW710OSqzyNkZ3v0qF@RUqh5twD95vYCHB6rX1Jq603j7Nl4vQJ6mM3YWwfsU2dF99KZ@Eo006Xr8xLKsFDsbeZ0O/Jw@a/BLgSP8SSRiChMOSp27VYbTLrlNd81eb7JvzLi7FZng52As4j7@xvPnz9HwnB72@jgiYHOIfhrlppGLMD2t//lPNq6TV0@b23/@rWHK3MDPEX6@e/0YzSda7qONjY8ePMhmk0Abbn76jadf393dzT5M5p7WcztZJb2x/Wd/urGh69t6aqPheVojWj8//1zW01lZ/fMfRZtPn37N82qZ/@Obb2savgrwusCSwSfDNDDiuwg/DXWsc/YanvMuw38yv@6EzAaaW93XLPI6AlyuRWb014wEZbbBtNpO4b98/@hVZByp6annLnzHkVeRfDHCjWAAW8a3XURqkW0Mlr@OzFLVahWMhf/ybyF@7asAB31m2/Cq5XxY@VmkplQpyptILQ8GTdch3f/rm98MMQ8XE1VS4/znPqvDI2cLurzTgGeLnm0JDwFT0qnUDf7Tive0e4zZ4/7YdPBj8Y9t4mnMSgV63cf1RCLRUBV41CZFSmmafgYCgC2wFo23EJWElbuwsFvAJ8IF/J5HiKeAqYivuFk4EKtxh@c3wz1f8lSe/2M/x1Ikv3HffFirgSjM1DJbtQQ9G2flMid/ihWKsuPcl9kWlFmaXo/gjfSqySxd1OVkMnkfKakjTRVd0C8SPZOjkciLOUl9ykbY3MbCTvSmgmDzMKvCMbY83D4@f/G//sUP/uL79PcD@v0HPC/N7ljd1BajmnNR4w@r1eSaK1@dkQUynC4Xy8VU8/ostgWSqnHMtPTHb6K5TPQEWwl6zuL@CGckeGo1fNG/sJGJvjfchE8tsFCIeZT14ZDTKF1ogsWyMqV@AdjU5jm69ZTYfSglWS@U5EZNz@lHNTmtybzc@psec4Q4iOzAswF/9A9PYN3AUeQNctvwfSjU7WdjGQacvOsfKVKvpxpmAxRZFmTj/kZ5o1jOl/VUcxVcBF1ZmhrIuwut3Wq1XrdbBjwto21oY2NyXy2oRVXfNqbGzBi3Jq1pa9yetDVNirytb7BjXgsaLOE/Z4k7n2eq2hRGMjj4UxRnGpEi/whPTWKRK3gab7fqb4GpRdJ1UYMT20qjlhAYwUdt3m8klOvruvpFolIR/9u1wFihh5sgI41rRdn@AmDVb0PlQOmtNr/YBrCJ7fp21dmjn9pE4iuNL2r17cW4Ivr9@wmUvvcBQG2zwaJZJ5p37rN4IrGpKBv1lXkAwA3QW7a3oWivt69r1/Xt6@vtbfjfpve1@ILr9fatf/rMnxVh5v4NrFBn9VTtLHUmGKoBdjVVQxc1dQaGGnwhHDRQUgRUlqkU2WJbkRHTChkwMbOsbemZVG76UX4fVKV6Q8G@TVWpa/lcQ@Ey7IXKygo/fl0r5uMqCqmm023ijkmVvZAiL959@T/j7@zdl3@AGgBoaCUpktrCjkOJ9x/g9dhmjx8/xt9j24Z/@D3mj40u6PDYrj22yZc7kOGxH0o4c5eFSomCg8l6MS83E9pMZ5FtOV9A0fELt55oNPpPXuilQpR3s3GT4QsPHH9h2fNPfmHVI0XelFAYtD3GsydFoEQiilKTIrXtIS4rw5FrBTsJn1U/V57tKtirNcY0F9HmPbbq4X61VKrxQffNp8RCWw@34K3B//6G5@GVmpjMFb5ar/Dv0Wv8ezXGv9M2/h2/wj92@hr/jsf4xx638O@ph3@nr/Bvt4V/p0P8e/AK/x6P8e9ZD/@kSBXU@82d9CDdTmvn2jkYLJZ2Wbqf7msdjdqjtMnSs/SMpYeO1gGTCX9pMFnpLkv3WNpO2xAMfME0Zukxmrrw6cFfFwC58GfhsoVzLd1mkNAAWyq6m4kSSKffgKyPn0l16LnKL0zQxlVNTat5q4GH2tflhl4qMhXLTG3WX5xFG3haql7KstbM3Dh7wSIeaPKVSOrsLMXHJJiereD599fXzeb@k4fNZgrl3Nlj52j@f3Q0DFvX/g@PnMdHztCB/6Ojo8fMrCXuJ5T78FRriW3x2YnUKjtnZQWFgi@HIqntnbNaRkFzPoEqCLolPvCZQ4RvbeNMijJQkC4rpIZVLi8qlxUyBFYwNCtBABGMG8CxItQ3cKn4etwlPBeX5IgvNF4@PwtM3JB6fnmG3RHoZwb/oOeGrf8V/q3/d/0/fsZi9QaoVbGr6@0YPXH8i8evrq@uxbsWj8WEJbYNf@gAdoxydV1DIwW6AlM9Fm/Er6@5G7xj8W0OsIZpbNco8jwgiIBIkCaly1@x/7pfTFs8Z3iuujFfIHB2Nk2n45WWf44zTo4Zb2ieNl6hW3k2W3Wt8Wc/otO6d@IUKJetVLQtxi16Vq9Usr6tUKxUir5lMxYr3X5q6R0tD3pVNhuPVypg2fHBpsEagC0CWN@SA6imZ7Sp3lciV4dHdI41iIlcJI454oIhlqbj7vHmlKhclu/di4kbWXd24/fu6aX0mzeBy2gETtqCU7PZsdxmE90zb97ITZkm7Es5sKeLb95o6VJCi8YdN/YEr9yBpGKKxj7Sa5RqyXGBFAXwZlpKn@PRNzxjPHZjr61RUsZFWJ4cpxsx0mnHPYv@9Hvf@tZZtFqVFZlcsxoCwFRYbns7n63V8lkw54tAK3nzil8O00uUtPj1Zkrm9GDyZjQivLRiIc6lYxT9odVkOzWo4h4@V9cRKneWzcVjIF7joMZdR/CPO2ulEnfP5mPFREn8VTfiNdAv@B/2ijOJ7FZh636D0d906YMiuXJlVrXr6pVZxtHF60pb3HaIezbNe/cyJaBpMV05k5rNh7unu81mVZZlbBThhY4k3CW8ZGnkRutU4LlSo465a5xFo@XKfWIOrZhjkWhFhFOi0EqwYomIIFld3JDteUzSxJjDhqTTF1@SGHXaAMcItsrz39NHu3v7p0l9G/Ql/WB3L6mfPHsQ0dCam9vJO4P24/3dh0fPIMLTR/u7J/sfH362/@wpuHvscv74Eli859@waYn9kj2XXrqvDdM0zIlpNi8nk8tX7KVlNS0g7GBiWZbTc5lnNk3THEEw/6nAr215xsuXhjuih7374Xfe/fC/efe733v3u99597s/@OmXP/gO/H4Mv@/x7/f@TSmH759@@c9/793v/C44/gf4/TH8fvLTL3/jm/xH9j@B338Kuf2J@IXC8Z8EsH75p19@/0c//fJXfhN@/1L8fvP271d/svz3g2@v/mG87//e@jDf@7fw@30Oyw/7vd/hbvi9Ff53eLhf@c13v/7v@P@fiT80/u67X/8TfAnLP/vNP/tP777173W9@Gf/@t23v//u29969@3vvvv2P9Xf/ca/1tLh1@@9@8Ef/vUf/f5f/9H/QP8/pvfvv8//u9/8Z3/5v/zl//aXfyR@P4HfvwPTT/7y3wPD/t0f/hD/v/@Hf/fHP8T//@lf/d0f/trf/fL/SIbf4ob/@1/@G/7@m1/9j3/729/96598829/7Sd/@1t/@Nf/@6/8n7/xH//mv/2Dv/nvv4WOv/WTv/7jX/6rb33nr779L/7qW1@ueH9n7fvL93D/8h/B5f3xfB8475OvD3X58ufC5x9CjXkqwCfA3b/07jd@ERj81xl7950f48pj@K34/7GuUZgfc9v/Bwz67TyjTxpM8Pu1d9/5HpLovwMSwX9Ar@8GlgUfbvnu3AJk/e0lkX7pp1/@ix@RLWKWazSSjO1oUS8mtqCvsVUqibZUDDJDlF9chBYAECl9FyXUgt93Uba9@@E33/3on7774W@9@@EvYyumZEvJ3aSirR/@gqZPyb1HOAyYf59wGPBzTD9BI7NK4nOwsc@F5@effy4136Rwifv9N@D6OTnxh3EvXAIvvHw/dMc18QzdQxZhTAvjpnANkiY0MNkEqQBbvn6Sy7BpQmA0xYE//II7BJpukXGKb3JF76mEr/n/3DiVWALD8AdvBfKNZBDxRBLcKOUgmcR06tOLFCbGlZQt7kKTVpRutsQwB9NpYgo9UTBACgnwepBg1Wo1gRGrHB@wctRqRUaoJBJVyDfG5nGSzSKCmD4gKBCzmjhmza3qlEdMILyaT46EhE7HsqbLiWL1ISRYnT5kCAuBE9gXL6q1YnVaQ3BvOT0S08QDwgmBVRPT2luwVwlmAkeqHr4FVIrVRKJWxAQxk7x4kk1eSDnKHOU9wRKiDOCL48A79xn7SNaKMp9A2UCC8dD4TsxD79CM3g74nyW2RHbo3zfSb4sIvkFJiVQY998hFXGHa40YAOAqiqqqDH44TbjD7oP3lINKULLwSXAICeII4oDAAdgQyyJB5ZsgC6QfqW598IPAMDObm5tSpCZn5COaT0pAZ909L/NbXd7wHlGZyfmSjM4mrTP3cYH4FUp/M4pDg1HGAbOPEvx3//4W@wiySd@5m8SURMbJ4qA9QtlOJGQd4NechPQF9A0k4FMC9EZSp1War0pIySRjajWCfuzo6EggQQ5fVKUEsLme0dCOEwyTySQCMVQ1qSaT4qvSlxxUYVDJV3zVTSQuDWUyXc9WoP9SYejEwv0NDTqm6Pj27VsoFVrsUT6ELiMT6z70bJE8wYFv8R0MZv5@BD1bknh/mWl5fsN6jC5gjLO4xGJsKy7xZcEcCf@JRfViMYqmOFBfjW35y4DyGrEDji1Gaoio//AuXDEX9z33jtje0ePH@09OR40Gk0y6GdNsjlynjTsy1jwxjLf75CHfNaCX8ohGpF7HlE/LOsofab@cJul4@PD48KTMOE1ECcUCSPEKjR4LUpQ0KTIaPd@OiKUSMl7V4sgn@C7P8x/TSxlMsFaRIm0T@x3AcPjPKtJjr/fAmUJnPSnLSS2PfbA4Dboy6etOuVx9q2ULEnzJPmF4qBjfgQzVENeWq9vbRDSpdqXQmDkaoYDzUq0m1hwxTaqd7J9ChNMjpulplUFX/ipb0LO5bE7P5PO5gq5l86VsPlfMpLV0Pp3Tda2UzZaKpcK1VPucTVXEVQHzoDow7d64v4krfeSztByix2Y9ncQ/PZOBN0BMarlCY2NjcKUggmfEFle4ZOsarFcKUuAr8DDpKxL7CjjBA2ngOiwmFsEdHlXESiQ86yPGlyPJWg6qcVw6A0bi4KRR@KmMoPpAZz70kyIb3/jGmNVq0ItWDg@kCIijPvNX4yhWR@2rxEediWuSb4@xjvWZhRf4qB3LGw2MGdTNtCpFrq@vuwDp8IDpNZ2sPEYH39dtcmmB@XpqSP//874PTSxsj2rAgNupERgNMGa3UwYYW2DMbadaYLTAWNpOWWCc1DJaejs1qUlM2uYnYzHceFuVx@YUD@LjbnLNMwddFTcaVGVKQJe3xUmTNRGvhjs2HKNTxd2ZuNI@Fr@SOtWO06ZbwqSO2nI6M9Ubzwa4In/guNUoaFlR38PCi1dxz1q1zhrqyBlBa6jnCom6lgaZjD@tmNSTHbU9MA13J1fOFdESTJfs5NLlS8vuOJfq548ffTIej45NWvS/ky2VOyoef4Eb1XeK5VyuUa/LcqJOyTTw0kFeIZWNDWBi0@go8O069thT9GIDIncst1qNRncymq5o5Uy6KF0H2ZeAcJinmoQxE5iXJBLvSnB82XZsqF3lpJG0rijf5W63e711lZhbJONK4TagyLViJFtXgbWihMKV2SSpWHNPcDG60LhcibmisqzninKlXpnbC3m50riW7g/NjmXgUv@z9NXtWHmQQhxqBBI6Y9J12XWccblldh3XnAfMaHk/IEfodoCsfB0kd5bGFK9uJ5fHQEBDTjngVH4OWY2Wt9VBcDb2oT2sN7b9E8qQQ3Vd0TNKRlO0DP7fYdDx//3D6/Cv4xtiZXTpFHfpPgH5CQ2EzR7hnsWxw04dh@6@e2C2V4TY6xu0jm/PdTzvHxDmgWGfc6@HFj8aK/D6xMBLL7yhNe6vCPFsNMRNlab7jwZhf9gCBKliU4AH8HIHjrMsQIE9e7oil4@DwyiBGPw0Sgh@fPjxJ6eh7@n@7t4nUp49OHry8MYnJwLl2KP9g9PAWuC@ftRcAOLr@48e3bSKT/bo2XF34rj4kw6OnmXnr8AJt4ZJWXgWAwXOBES80ArNc4XGmzdYruAbNAkXF9@DXtg9Yczl58Y0Gp/zfW@WFyx25Rscy9KpvxnOYCiAWiZr872z2C2kM1aE0qgVSpI0YrZzyQpp1nEGAwPvEu1ugGPfwE0@JqpBA7ryFpO@dNxB59LqmBvSY9xPVNLwwkREQvoEgAwnbTrQwBpLeGJXB2/5xFmL1mBisgnepLvCET7ohEbX6vWhgbl0/ABSyzAYrWf5sAfim@FnvN5hzNMgt1s@g9vBpYhkjI1IsXLvnvbUhZpSS5fLPXN/ClzKnkGtMdxZspiTM2pbPmBqM8J6Vt1rjKCoMtm8hkoRaLEbZ@mUkXXsynmZbaacUc27Nq@hTUpkocnZ2Bh32xVZhsYuVwZy14rpvTTL7mT/5rd//Pd/@msg7bZS8IposozLmjc0SSV1WS8Vc8VSRi8mi6ViNqflc7mkpiehN1IogcKY1opavpgraclitpQBFiyBb65UkCJ8zVhqi0DCtwxg7Tbe6bdNGrfar0kRPnHFXseMOIsYgX3CZBPiyHiLuzemfZNbVlXWs0xLM@hsAUSDtVnk4GAvfXAgyw/QghP2e2lZ7qAlV0ynCw9k2SSfvSJqELLD4xTxaBR5zC3p9IM9WZ5wAHiqqCz30bKfxzEcWbbQsrd7cIDpdNGiY3wIds59uGXgWwoQzEZLJkMLCGT5VQAOwu3yhLKE6T5aME30OeA@e@Anyx/7@KTTAOGYh@MQPvHzursry4fcsruLPnuU8RxH9VO07NIjyy5YoD7Icg8MPRdqoiy3wIi1QpbbYGrPDHDDGxTx6El7bMjyjBMISSTLUwpttM9luem7YzKffPKJ0R93zB5/Zi7/tgE18LGmk/2D1scft3q9ljvb3f/4GH329j4xurOJ2@q1RLRWEx4H4oDP@XB28wEcD5tNY7DU51PwsW/4NGdNE3FrGq8AJ/H0MJFhcw989sBn2ZwfhwbPEIK28HkwhO8Do0U@/kM@9J22WnIFGRWVWLoGGeoM3UicHBpt16mgfVrdYCwaiyZn9Xy6USEPNgR1NV25pvuPY/g2cHAgfjWrT6vpRnVaLeh8sUg3Jp9N9ZwlJzeGO1opV94wdjQ9m5iWcfe0042yqKLtsJh2b@s1iz2J7@iZbFk@29lR5LrW2NG1Yjlf@GJrIsvxMr53MoUyBExHoeuMr3i90Ngp5EJRCoWEkdLLhUK8cg3kGENL3MJOezMWuzSN83gc0cUuHmSB3748o3xalW5smpxWOV5sFq9Mq1qFn4rG0rdgdfAIzkl77LgcYg/ATXfSZbrfWdZKRRnST6Vi8ThIJhIi8J2vM3v@tdPz09PPQWZB51l0PZ/yS0MrwvrxJ3sq9EaFDY/OVA@ws@C46h4KlgUffrKj73QKGrX6CTR90J/w3XBHi@sM1P1p2xxhj8P38A9EU8UxVurpJwtwTqDfzVPGDcEVOn/CbpsMTxa1Osyo1sBkdFiMsGJG/JIa3WatVm1Wh/yK5loQ61NGx27OwRx6HPdgmzJFv8JdHsKjWU1fV1rVaWQKcJpVpmgvhk7nhZ5oVzp4oOiD6gOMXGnCt1UxqyZeVC1H5Ep3x64yNrE9o2s@NV3cdH94tAkqAG79iHWZGd9kZ3St9R7q3ddKzWX2HLMnk2HMUGqt@KJTyIqkiX3Nz/IV7UXCWfTrSrfKYl/EK6/A6m6yWEd9EN/JVjqxB6wZB5f0i@6LLtNZPluhm/5iCAkqEdGGrouOV2ufgtbCAZ@Xy4CIKONzgIkpAVirQx5GfGRdV9rVAYspbMriRJ5spVetY@w3@NpWZLmhKPU3DammKM@lGtTTyixiVL1Ji06hZumWpqfzlSm4aYVspQ8Fa3wxrbjV0cQ1KwOwinEYvuXKqAA5gWoA5vWb2Ltf/GZ8W8lVuVuFQL0ZgKLQVJvVacXGc22AJaqZKngk6tl0Evqj8CokoUHW80ktn8wks0mlgK7QGidzSXCEPgm0/LFBTGZMTqanaVVLaqaWjKVfWJ0X8eR5DBQNIhmLJ8fOPt6SDS5QSMiVZIWvweIJfWvAoBQcZmwrxKYgKSqYMaB5n42sZB9BHZvGgGLE4wrLbMUGmzEMs3k6Ge3XG@Xy/nT0NfCKKa928olCOvE6Hq/ENuJVz3wl1SpSDaUK5Xq0ATwrhqiYNxnWoYzHm1pBL9frLcxhIZ3MpDOQOav5prct1@RGMr2R16CErhnpMYwLDK7LzLWRuVsTNWW8cp5pJb0iqbTcglLUYnpJXzEsGZdwoZ8AKI2EsEP6stiZ7G86jEWjBT0ajUcrOGy9IYsxSJBw/PZ6ELXRe9qODPqTXJZLOgaYC0raV5YOq1DXEvbuWbYkRa6k66vrbeiepmjdHSqDG2RS1Np9KVJmDPS4M3FySWqDsQ9dzpfYrn3Bv2e4mhjgSnQuHWiOtMbGtLBPxT7DPbQ7LAqIGe6wruuZRl0vQPsGMtMPqutaBYfqI7hsWa0B5b0rwG87UcPtJ5@y2cxIKD5l7zHWS2xKlOnITbLvVnd7x7sV37aHo4VnkizLlagcuYpGotfwJ0Xu054Xne95YZHQrhccjsaRXKDP2whJDLZ35Q8dlfF2lJhR5vKh3oi/fWINrooZhY8PgMC6vo5spqhExNaByqcv9ByUke34ewmgT4PjMNB05XI41BlJvRh539CLmceHR/ZD98AUOwmK2aZci7C0puDK/EpZuOb4KmG5VNRl/TwZYfcjlQg7V6JamXYbjE5KXxS@KH7x@NnRs6MDKXK28WbDwVFw5lOFvbW/@jXoC0Qz2ShjZ9XItJqtiEVVtZqibet4JFCBlUHWd7W8kn5T49xbI4@8Dj7vfvE3s9PtIth1UF7LUIK5hF6raVs6i0dG7778AzwL4mr/s91HLOoZM/b3f/ojvfD3f/qvaLFS9Lri0ZBrIQIh0ajlC5Grq9HV1TU83C8XaUQ4UtlCHMx8eF@L1FKanrFtu8LKKcPYKiSy@n27khJhtYIWj3hKRExiFHIR743w0tNF8PJnGchJzmMJRPaPrZyu3d9GntCCfVAs@Ns2vRIwRfHxizeMgaVd6/R6lk6mVIqV3yps@62yzd7iKP1bZYO9qNZwZljD3VP@uPQWbhLByZ9oLZHaijI9B37160ojwWhkG/p3X5jmln12g6PPNnAN@qLTlg1/5pZHfxjJd/DA6tvMrZeeHNuKp1Kdjjg5aNtkuRqwwlYKMDuLv/vF39D1/N//6a@@ab5pfq5DH65Uymt65Gfaz34GAdbs4Pc7YDSAj1vt0RB03NiKi7OhVypF8Db1LuPh/W4cdtxQe7B6NvTG0SZdoMZDpdTkx0J1YhRsCzf4Jkl/pkNb4hVJCvRM0o/dXjtJMNgWXmoAtVS6kr6CXtCssioITukrc1DgMISG1Gk3vcHEHdG2gBjF0xpJdg@iQApfwRO3NmhjspC@Cgis1NbtqBxlj6hG2hEbmp6H53dBeyJ9BaKIA@jwrmYD99BjSMsGca9iEMKTPDp1SLsBaQ94hCa5xij3PECScex4JBt0aOkroBYQFSzQFpi1DQEqIGK@AgSAPMQEYKvBtlkmzq6sRKIyPxzsGldB48Fnhr9/V8JoCK2D@8X9yBUMB06gu@OVR8gXooRBUQs5@kA4DD5dWwXtH6OTDdUv2mD/3qAAFh1mE6OssXv35lhVq1YnzihHCP/cGuGYE5WDvRxXAOb3nD7qlOUkw2PXKr5rwHZA8QShC1yn8PPWKqGoTEbrtSTB/3szLXLkjaIijwpmQJQXrxVtIBlERrLzMmyz7SrT9EKcBci3Afc2IUVHfQXdwbPpR6r@ue95DRj@LOIfKA6C6DQ8jif49uYGbgYN4ARPc8ZjfLgwEBuv@UE9KNAOx37sIBZkxRpQ6K7lQleFJpH9U79iGS2O0eanpBEetK5ZzzJcXpyL44diYWgGXwPPtxLpbNAZHW0HCtQbOTYdiEWHd@DabeAIkFHiXCGO9sS@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@CTweGB4/P1OchHZ5eanSkXwT11JND4@u9/DO3dSoZ4F27KTG5nAkLgmz8HJIAXduUviNFXgT886U7kAu3ZvxryR1vapYrhGLdr0oNo4XeDJ7b0hH@eAZOh4x1IFFtzq0Y2KFCec/vZG88vmvjPynFKPXCIQxBDNNzpLtJABLttrnye5lpyI8LqhCAnAoRdN3xGMwXd8y9HyTNeoGIZwx7ZPw7a3BOU1hAiSZD6LOk@Y59EPOfKuwj6wpRLLNS7brusYsRv5xDI0MHJuR2sNm0OyTDxihmWFX/ExGa1qfNRaiT4Po0Kj5nR/m4jk90tV6oPyATvSfcv8p@E@5/3SeqJ9sfdrgKhk6XWN2kOvxeDc/JIKZ@WGu@WGWcx@CDDo20zgIDDlbcLuGX7tKsX16cxuUY9VnDOCJERDcjKXqX5zVzxq2Z15uNRKpHjC7TISAEgfQ9QbR9LITmJH6g4vByPEWnGw81Q9aJYE3OrX7ghs4r2AegwIixuD0svAgtt5QTP1zhUBkGCCgHgaeqBrsjmNWvBIcCEuewDh1eU5jjlhdINMg7Ut4CTdQlzjpOWHDgBohQOgeZAnQBB/m1xx@UYkvHZ67eB@7H1ahuxWGeCBQtBEFSt6oKlzWVKiQQlgpio8mkB3V1erNrPj@UBT1G16hbF6L8g@jv/HB6HehXizHnhiWNxgVKVxVcP0aqBCiuhBVWa0aKlfAILVlDEwXWq59rp@K1hqS2Ur53QyeDmbBu8TbV2Ohwm/HefnQ3jXZlssBK8yqVcjirMqrJa8XPkk5wYNonog28xlBxOcCBGCkl0YzRbRpONq0WuWCg01XRLsMITklJKc8Cg89XYFkQ0SD3lNwbTcWTwO0U1wtJwM8jTejoAaNZIZXsOJM9Es8rAznK0Wac5lDXCB4CFVs5LN2Y2nq9RDSIaF1AwAy4i0AHX7nWVm6KfA0JbAFMoqT0pdR3CbYgMsKYDASwRV@oGcsYDLqA4PCLyeoHYC6KyfqkqzRCC/@pflPTvqO/k@77ZheDKktOqaTN/7@URwbSNlQBQ1pH1o6iwIZezLPxGX1CzpHBK8H7Tug1bUuHRZbomyDe8q/5z7VGjit1NDAFSV4E5K4HXg0i/v9B5wdYfdHztgYO9lsmXeaLGK7ZenzPoPVsx08QD10kC/oeh3H9OzoGAq17fRsyzOTDM9bOzdFt8MU54xLYT1ZGB1PksRoJO/GImjOV6jqNpt4N2OzGcP1cPFysNCWlsche0ajEvZ/wRSKD@JJAD0axZzWS7M9jt8NE8@cFtFOrfZ57GgkPKOQyC4DGdYG/R98@6DBMM@Z9xzp9FtUpVvjGN2s0HeGTg@0vomnShj7BvjDOWxEyBiNCJckM7BLWw6dPE61JNZOGnER9dMPjso@1WNGPIivLwJYIEaSuTdpjJR1lyTXXJkcj@and/Lh@J6E8T1Zjy/1wm/izLvmVe75YUlnYnMIEHCORuZuNDDrILc6t9BZQCVwRr2KR3hvFDu0YquDmO5C0F0RXO0CfyQDmwe2APHPVtF/fQH60ffft/gMvLD2ZAbyZogLCWN0z4DnT3PGIPhhPC5FliQXsPbD90wLwuJ1QweoQoAaS4LLxoM7oWKOoNvtBcfJ@4Dv4HlcJHWL72nlVJV7LsHJvUiyc311ET1sdsyBMTM7MREyGYLr5/gYOmwkr94v4yjoSOg5vK8Xg7YrHvhCM45E54HKK1jGSF7E46vZigexAu6hkXLC8HA1/dD/lmjGIb4qH62GfkA0GsHh2AsLhz9Hs9GMnw094FeVCDnK2x9ekrg//26CAB3EATjJebLxdeLzOBZk6T1ahCCsuphlPLrVh4jnx9wuww8j0d05hcINRar6pSwt3nOwvMStdSUe4gqfJ/kU0vux5F1M9948F2I1DmwuwvY@rAm5BRlXZrTbsTBE7rK2xBz7lkxANxqns1e0Ks0lAjWISZJubFF3m/SLuIQ940P44oDTZ/BFgD1z3OQM5ecNx7TEvS2MfIbGKKS1CBdQ0gFKiIqc5AKNUCjJN0Pwq@sgzfbKNNu30mwvpBnUgMUkQ4Gk9kKSohSweNYVwcDsjldIZ/TCvjN81olteGzHcHG04ipqRctWkkUvomUQyFEzWt6PgVCOdqLlh2TwouUTMpxHy5@CYV63om@iZb9aYAAXrGS4j@5ChKO9HS3vxeLX0tg4Nz0/XTVaDsoUwuxwK1EESIH5Bq0Rp9hsR2Rz7JrQsJFSmWTIMV4Su080DpOkXxr@@c0ldAMCeuIY5xYFZgmmLTQaoRaDpwPNhn/C9pKaXBat@f7RAa1sCoJgMgno44XjEHhQwyPRRWHEEUNfmtGALyCIcrO8HCMWasneEx2ROnAoFfJi@kQ9lfSBToz86xC4MU@ErqsR8f3yWgTBC/D98MTIq/C8hY6fHGGEc7LxJWghUV9E12QKy3oRF1H64RKise7FQHjjsx@ElxKBDcl00OFocg4TGzmjRSYhX1z3boXj0KAcr5TIvTeikVQQNXOFNzmLnKFgCFf@@LrshOIhagsiCD3r6QavZUG7QLIYveayLqSp8soHKIRkDtRws31OVwE9FEYKx8VNktqKVc2QH5cnSZJrUUxCZBUPGpoYY5560Hndx@OHPqz76sec4lhLDAGEYgapcPnqfID@7nD93VeofSLcSGCZYr28Kb2tXq9tZW9gPpgne7sA0TPJHsaXKkdBCnOSQ@8gpJmv47VbKj4u@eBKPk80gH5D2/fJFvQJ7qDbzb4Fh4Vagnux6Hiug@O5vppQtzWSwYXqKy0qpiTg8IwHmM6zth5XnvFlRYw@NL5tDD64gN3FAg4XHsKjDLg3SM5ruTuxaZXLvG6D2OYuKFK1MuOCnKZLg2KeO4K4p6nbYNoWHI6axw@Pnjz6OjS6hUIhLtro2Rw/rLU41hq04xwyLZMO2oMl3RY9ibd74GQ3DsfT7eobZ7Z8S5ZwYQ3KgAGp@Own6nhcyLKQPL9RdyEeDxuiqIB1Pq8GxoJUQlXHwCbbEnQdA0HMcWzLEEB89RbonaTeWpzusWg28UbtZpOar2YTFy81m6IVw6LxZ8TjP4tspCaeS7cM8ktYLiWJjhBgD4/Y8092T9npJ/vs4Nnep@zrR8/Y890np7gV/OmzB48O9xj89p@c7DNpYaEkXliFHUqg60OzbeK9gnhKW5YR5D1nNONyJ7YX5@4nxpB94rRNnKba9ozh/T63qLY5rvFY@9AdneEYpkWXkg2tMa63oBu1oBuLyk2H9urhqn4GYVvQpx1in3fodKyuBWEl7PuOLNPzt3exgQUlCPLW36ub5EoSXp5FS4fomjtcgXUJ0Q0Ij3M3AMbg66/o0nLL4xHMjsoE4YLngyl4un/8@IThYQN7R08eHp4eHj05YQdHx2B9@vXDJx8DPQ9PTo8PHzxDLwr4@Ojh4cHh3i45cATSKsPt/i8n3ngtCioGJ6q0z3Hmm@6mD2yLo96owbNLg3Yteiw6sVH6WMbAem12ohVp4qH6gjslaaqAxTZ3jz/@DNp8Zr7CGU5/KpjWH8jPPLrEbTPNtik1qCw1qG8VUV2h2VO0OM1HDGcM73QwK7SzP0bmJPOB0yKejmUyeQ/XqODYNz8AgOqyDxoS2gDYCMpfsFJldBdLNJrcJpA1SK09cPCMRp4aX0QoLBj1vr/UpCIRxcRaGQSKOxcObRwP0iqBA/A9OOgi2bHLA7BM4MADsCx3QFX0ENeOsJwIMRkfTVA8szx3eDkcHdC0MCsEDg8M6sUWBU683KhIDRbcZYXHIQzoxh0@ykM3ARpe27Ioikfh8TaawYBXDJPfgwYykU8l0to2CCmDsOniVINY9sYvDEVf4AZcJ2R0xx6LVeMqO8XFQaZt8buOegPD5kug5kt3iPdYEU@2qYpTxa3gjiDaCzJyiAHxfrJFPIJ4D4VWaL5vPIj54FaKhlgjSff0@UvQ7kLgwS0Efh4wAEhZ6Om0qaWijaQIxukKVo55DnAkjtu@DYcHdu5M2uZCBLFqK/bSev06LoicXOgn@esUCTsootemC2olTWV2HRfqOIlVulUFpWC774zGFi/D2GIOaMaJmjkIjQ0bpPaiWltIDelwM0XbsUOJtoCLV6TaAqZ8n1SJ4/nceSC@5ldsAudDI8zX3SE6RgvvZp/PnSVxEunSxOEXUIRprhwHP2djwoTrn9JcdrxleEtfsVp7@OBMefsiiVf1cbHAb8f0Fx3iDxgT04LqQfN8tGDRRb1L1DT/iiVv0sLYYg2ekJZYy31g0A/sW9Cvu9@sBH58ufFtd9wtc9OdHN@8qfJYCkomcWGq14/NpVuS/T/FPe1WGzuSv@mnEG0SuqHdtkkgBGMSAybxLIEMhuTmGOJr7LbTc43t6zZg34Q5s/tjX2D3/z7Cvsq8w/zap5itD0mtbhvC3ew5N@cEd7ekUqlUKkmlqlJdVelRmQshTUAM2QnIgqx31BePYGp5/Ro9ZLAXikCRPsoR3LenLjCSIkS17vK6A5JF3iMpu1vDd8UOWVTE1@qij4vZH7nPzm5pdcfNxQYlwiCno0S0pyAXXNcwS6H5agbc/sPgQH4/Htzmg9jx9PC7oO0/CO134ZZdvR8WT0sGrMeD/esDYHly@z@BhbZ79wPmSXIWmuZ0zZzeUkZb0z5c488zfUdjD8Dg3IsaFA3UqO26T0fUKiKywwVcE0y8IKqd7ldOToTN@xMoC3IPtwxtKQYR9qJ4H1vbhn0Sdr5eNOnNsl48qS8Jizb176HBPJd494gKuQbxJD20sIgvkO6EE5Z6cmahJQRZ35NAVJRLYvdVyaCoLgHfwR4QkI07zWigNbeZGZ58wsg0Apd083htbNrwk4U1z914O@NoagIybYKaXfQsmd9/H3l9vKXq4QUWRuPBBrdhJQ3zDewTalDxEDL6frIHH@gW1aVoZM8L7IyiHRp@5ZMr7B9nKGIkXoTzWtgQ63JxLFHj9fGSWuaQQSJOA0209JSJbNEMCUrE05dts0PdeNJzklMQLDLxvr7XJldA8Yu7or5B3onnyZJekJtjbYmwqSssL1A7K2EX78/0BG2hN9LiIV0VSNsHq8r@/1TFs0SiJkXzuY1RiQB5Y3392fdgp1uhimd/FDbPIWn5Ob4awv4@BhlNI1LvA@dWjzyVHjPAA6Rj03o1YFIFYakzZ05JtJ0mIxM/wIX1QoAMRiLHKxDTtbpiksJtPnSekUzolGWmDcYQ1g3lUTND/buHq0OB/N36Fn9/fTzYMBOaDt6hVf67wSgKYq88I56K8Qk9WZPfgtGoT9nYn@kKoTjkxvSgsx1527HBK7cKE@m8zWxJR3onsdmtp3QNVAmpF3289RS1e8W0ei9bKJpNPageVsQKBRDsJHSR9sh2DdmzGPYfQoBkMOklcPogH74n0Rb8Bxw8BRLIRN58DtHG/S5uRBFYNdfpfhhpFiplayHd@52o1exjcA/PfhIJ23sKBUkLWzk@cOdp1vPFRHlALhr2HSjl2VnfpqLwDRW6CCkJgnsTvxsTFnpqKEvJB@6qb@YKm/mNlxa1ru@Nvav6ywtvpVWyBUy@zf5VdD26bf/SHXy56YieGP7lctKa/varEOvPxTO8vu4pR4ktbJRyFHnzBfzdFC/zxLkSwVcU8fbcFsLn@/GEWBbxPry4KPhuONo0b6GHRIpLxcqV4kJ0sRuXruobF6V@KV@8qvcviujkN14tjVcLqw5@eAqzKMgYPpmvjy9wTjW1rkH/RuC1qXS9nXQNEeQaAl/eNUfh4LB89CahjcMFAKrApK03KdT5xtMFtGZD3xO/H9w6Uk3mCeRYCxdI1gJ5BRXQu530yaiOaYeAGfSKB6vZaEJ/p661kPevh@MBpag4gcha4lv4zVpQbkx50ihAlnqoognSRe/RJM7j4MEQf52yFXW2wMu1AvpOugaIOpYkcWif2zb6FCKi0perfmFFftBsfUEk8Irfb1RMbG/Thb/AapFPWjw05WiOyGEif4GPeAACP0M6bcAqaOUekduHBc3H9wI@8BfSUY3JT4YM5C1aKWIKmn@Lr@TfROW3gQBM@AVec/lSxSlXXrCQZN9BUi5gtLHkxh@PGdCtkjtlARuLsLm@UgycLMWJRlitJBN8X7hFcjKt4J9sQbZAbzPN0Pldzk4koXNq@RYhLalLKWkHf3pxMccollXFVGaDFAvfpQZqumB79C6AYTUVe0GvB0gzLRZicuAj@ffK@ld1/VEd67zQyHN6diY9m0j3OZ2RinP5MMHHmbbMTHbma5zvTthxNm@mrpKgxYsPPd3yYUkS5y0@lDfyx4NGGGfe0V3JXKkTthMJWSPl85ze55TFRBnN4Dq9zumSv9dkz2ssE3lfJ@vHX0t2UEDGs9LWJMWlfj/svbLk7bAyBdnMBmoKwcWxv4nteFBKH0wpTmAFh3p@GrY7pRjKakFJHBoz9s72a9uXi4xXThoN9mKcGVhzxohBJapzlQg3IYdFqIeSFw0QBBMZTaiRu6MKT2XhqQEWcy2qatkLcmaAQ9PSQ7yEfpHf8I8a7EnkVL7M/MQFxnzCjWfv5iSBSOgu2vPJlJQm6C7CH2WjHphF4rqnaYjzhcSRoQXWdQbsg91BNfiilhOmoFCSYobuOkVSOs5QUOx7Xxdi4p31z9yK9aYJa@xhL5iIMm4zmuSFZSUc3MdBNI4wyhNFpYmuh8MenjrSgu@WXKhlzJC1dTxuiSEaM7tvVdGyh/N7@CQd0qGQL44R8i0aiMQJ0XW3i85k6AE7uEXRihqXcOxb5f6UFRowZp6tsZt5IK4jPjWF3X7XRIJ7jkcPUjoaNluBb8EaLYLVj8VN7YTydkbSp6PfCMYRgylty7L@fB22ftl7g@e5Lwr5ZwWDZDfyODjvP3seO1gBkVTCWh6WseuF55ZlnA23@Gw4iwA9cYgT/QfgzeAm6PcDqwwzBmWMYNEaBaOboO1b1kmgD4ERLrIynkyiH/bgetRi5Q4suprAjOglHHl8HAYchr84P/NxcYvOyjwLD63i02bo6puwjQRUHiedAZ4O04EFhglgemChq2AMRFlxRRIlOnuWuNDa5QoVUUANjHNinE1oMvQH47AFPUOaLKsHoPgYJK6s305hAvW1ek10DvbnIYDuMTEFFALqKOkhHCx5aP67cBCyYeqMval6JgfSb0BjBYZ7MApB@sYEpl6hYgbu0MGnb6s1UTs@OP1YPqkIeH5/cvyhul/ZF7uf6IwbD8opFK54e3wI0kWfpvOp@TF8sMs1KGlTglU@@iQqP70/qdRq4vhEVN@9P6wCNAB/Uj46rVZqnqge7R2e7dPpO0AQR8en4rD6rnoK2U6PPapVFbPicuL4QLyrnOy9hdfybvWwevqJajyonh5hZXiqXxbvyyen1b2zw/KJeH928v64VhHYMGu/Wts7LFffVfZ9qB/qFJUPlaNTUXtbPjxMNfT441HlRJCRgNHK3QpgWd6FLSzWRO3cr55U9k6xQfHTHhAPEDz0RO19Za@KD5WfKtCc8sknTwKtVf58BpkgUeyX35XfQOMs5ztUgX7ZOzupYCgkpETtbLd2Wj09O62IN8fH@0TrWuXkQ3WvUisK6/C4RgQ7q1U8gTfYUdUAA6gF6fC8e1arEt2qR6cwZ5y9R3sHFzr5IxAGsCxD0X0iMJpBYGuBSMcnnxAq0oE6wBMf31bg@wnSlKhVRiqgRcXeqZkNKgQinprNFEeVN4fVN5WjvQomHyOYj9VaxYUOq9YwQxUNMj4B60ClZ9Rq7CfAix@BWS3FuR51p6geiPL@hypiLnMDB9SqkluIbHtvJc19jItrKFHCAeoMmlemYqUz@@kmwDCTsxqZ@ToaHTFp73i/AjOyjFtlxwlnMOtspkIpmWkw0@hEeE2ErGkHl9fdRtjvDNDHVBdjxcdV1PXwShgXL8w4tx64kEPqV6hAJtNofCg3YKNbazRc7zElE2h8r4RUgz@Uy5VtxDsAcOeNip@tLab7doJQO0/lQScZ6uEBBOZk6j9l07fmVeCKXK4dyGLovI@Aleoo4mOTL3iUAqKRnB3xVo@4StJM0Hso2YEKOgq832qgnhQtIynTIII//W/xC08OxgeQzqzuyuVwE0tohL8FqhquhEIi0B8ZkSDsUJV@FAS/dJ28WR3u@f3uYNB2XFeVobxj2Ad2Hfc7xS@Dbqp4Nl2ekKVjZxl6P1L7blrC6PNnSTIh@8UfUcsc/NMY04@rsOGYD6g1papIWS2Vls5TLo4WSZ6QoS3QvYI6Gdd878o/VT/ibi6/9ryY@v5Wf@exhfaCGI4WJrw6lbugn7cXnAEGGMXiAJKEMkJGLmeUUfYmOvMtZPyCmW7DNlr@wFz9JaB5HUgCC9nrZs@sE2fjUTgxsQc5/Oak/G737OAARCdi@3xz/cVG0dJht37y@PcT1kMxYynq2BDmcVinUZIxSvZg4UMjxYiqHbM/MXAuhxkxhLrqNPqIcR603UbSkgkFGTY3witu@miiZwdIB1tQAI5FS/Hr3JEpGcBJNNXF1lw1J7TEb8JaiXhAGrP0ptRrE/yDsPXwV0NcN0gykGQxiqILnAu7C5J79oEyFaXNDQXuwSy@rfiYw7hpGpCqi@xn0buW3iRvG70YsSkjjlfqdioJSCymsRDKrqLPI/s9xRmRCmCKHgZffpL8Bo@fZIA7CnfXjMblcQ3IeKBLop46VkbLRtcl5IudEnTR06e6pm2BWn5XIkVjT6qTdWAQYzQQKnhtCdr4JgEXdRyRdJVkAft62RVfmVMxeAfCKUqOle/AufOaI6EUVfwQ@a6iUgiGpYOcMNVudR2WyvJJx7FQ5EyQ6YfoQfD/QJrMgb8NO06AHlPLCAL4KEoSVKYVbF@JKOGtOmgwTjdiapqfPsVg7syO@aIbJk9vJuxfAySQvTNVHz5R2MOOM4cAyOSo2DDHrzZJ@9KErdNr25XF8Zyk37oaOkLOFWqqmIGb3bjwaNnlqbMVfHGFy7omo8JDKCpe88btkkY9bJlSW3nxJLIZnKvif@RWSAGiBzxx6Re2Wk1zVl6OMiUHZKglY8Jp64hJsCy9u/fUbkUYITITsl@efClCAegdxGe2nXS3x0CweW4y4iLNxOKUouBhZHDcJuPkI0PWXZIhZi9AOE/apAzB6z/GtzhB9Bg6heqLoQnnCRmKYCWx1WEcZxDFresDaWlavdXYk2YSOVRjf9bnkPQBa7VUDp8DfEgMTXd5X7xrTgHl3uOazSyWW6kNPLRdxMpYLSHL41UnrcFgBEvHJrYbcPTCqeuLj1LpEPSj65GMXwjzWTiSGgm16IdqcNnEu3eaZjgaPKEWhWP0Vmj7xB/UpKsALUQ5PMkkuyEcYF7FoztK6RhOVgvC2Y5TtoEmFJaUiLgtNsS3b5yLCSpDhgZEwTDSmwuy2aR68NxBD7/bwegXnPtxCdRvB20dmdQASbpA7qRqn2I8tsbc9OEgIo0GdAVqQDQlCqxI04aqMEe/kOwk7ZrsODomxi6llvz@ejSTKmspqChmXFk7MN9GFjoTqbQmQ4PqYKGFtXVCZd6G6@7ezRhFC00eWwv7vK9FyhYvIkpP1NIRn1hu6qdP@CSV/KUnEY4e@IJn3HIJigjjmhXPVWflHOGHNgUfw2DUNnWisJJpN4eofqOtz6BPvKhUhzLsX6s5joIp7ABauXCSIxgN50@DL/3G3qDX7IaDsAn7NAzoPmGJh49TesQO644GtxHd4kMJbSNTexo/c3wZDsOG7/pcsmiE5orGwdAxzRTGo2n5C4eJIM05GgHGV1USfw/TMdJ0mefrcSEr6X9K9ngFt3hv2WeFeYX5RB8BSAG3k7KgYB/SMTkmGc6nxZkMlw9lMHC8FFnRdO@x2Etg/BJIRMcwCYwVMjNmCWYjcGd2L8b19sRrUwzCEQZaCvYDvHwmcuiz18Tbf0GKvEJLgS1R2MwbRfkUZYJxCPFhej@51178wdgDAj@AfuHZPG6Zxwgk4joq2lLE@xUZZRRwIfPAkGQ0SWKQYmEXZqFeAmhjkoaaTJ7eRw2y/IFFkQyzN8OVOCId2PjgZXNOA0ROY@ripLIsll2K24FLkPLYyd/PsMH37Gdp8OMhLmvOUDDtSciOgfR9pGoBlfD@05R5rYkyx1T@/ohZW3tsr6UIWJpncmbc8@vYauVCHighz694rDUYgTC2U9STph7L0XgwXH4k9e6VHXMjs82jdct1v2sIzMxWgslypU2kLU3xcVq00vikmCZJMbI0Ax7C7Ss9azZPE3FSauB4KzWm36HDfTSL7ab0pKL7u81jHyfFG7ToVRONHlKEOwYpLerv9QY0vHG/BJEweXvVIInRQJHRmPKjASpFJk2lx1OIuE/inqJHGyiH9baBdmb/3EvUtJGcCnmqkhJBLpGeGLgdnTZBLg07aHyBYeJ4hauFlF5wTrwpHeUVspcYZBgTGCCuioNsrIdiDW7cWSk@otsBOk4DrYUKKIngace0cNBB/zXBKCq/VO5Ii4fGNFu4KDKkiYYEuwrK9RAk5W8Or/XGhKDMkAKG@BxS6BbNyKYvj2/Vj7YF8gEELk3J0tI372FjXLEK2MAfM6kxwTVwXJUsmRhRyYHQINEAYwF2Kd1ewNtVXP2FI@Z4tG6Qwwg2EPzZwZ9VWQLDeW/kNbWxyKQ9xSyuJDePNldkd7hIzFD8juSXQ5GXurRxBQABYwzlSwWAgGFNCXs8FKDQOybnJRCVfQQFSwUclvCRoqLGdp5z0pGoMsPzdSNHfl6OlyaM7FwgsLCYnydGBNYs87PEUGCim4uLkePF/PbEOWBBrHifKQ5dIXslSUPdc0xAugY578YSpV4QXl5yMCU@X3cTiZq/KfVl3kjNp1OBPhrDeraQTt3MJ1IT1a6tJYsmSgI9XLPWRCKQwjUR1lLhx/6Ra4oZ8lzbhBqbjMQqQ9pn4zXVsMuEfZv/l0hsk1O2WmMoeKZnuNp@NfiKlURQ9ocDsItlOjLA2O0/3FplmaowkXcFUFw65ezi8IaQVqw2TvXYLNzpqkh7OkCB2tMOOuLD6cFBIuzr5VQZGl0Fo/V8Po9MfGkGv1e21ahKCge5ZO5c57rXyw1v/zT6cJkj2R8EdCXAltpBB9AlMCgifzDq8s0QiANkxdxZ6ciKe/3rTse8ggFPKLHzoNs4p4yGIGgCCrXRy4dTUgARSDnB/owNxPb9LPTou23yQlNCUcdQUBpNgm9sdXoG5MEPHbTP1idVBAwFs7JmgnnLLe18xRkEbzahzqLwxe7X2DzZfhv0egNPfMR7gDFSwMJdusDBgVkgz1nwhJG8e68jikfrieAm7Bl@xZjF5HUEpyYmdc@EiguPsfFPgm5lMnTs@mcbphVo8io2cxXjU3vC7tquDBb/CLDMh4D2o3JfNYdOi@iUzgxTvRzB8RNg9Kzgzd37JLK4pBOTNPt@biTqfHR9CtYATXdpLaBi2VP3Ukvuya6Ja59PCh2kYZ5hSJww5srjSqCr2R8nFm/Gnc7jpCJdA8Ad@7skIt@E8mMCkc4AaATK4Qf0xCja/5KFYX2QCijCCxy8rGNW7mCBBhawrCet0q@3TrlcFkvD1VVRLu/CQzYryrtlsY8fdnfFPrzv4vvT0tr6epFl7r77FT7uqo93YhdgkIZztfVltA@vkFZCvzG01sYuXsqVlrziUqO0vVOMcvXyLrr1w9M//vXf//Fv/5Ery5f/wpddeql/1pl8388ttb4uPb0r4nt9/2J56bK@NLxY7haRy/5JUcMH1XG2GZuP@qNLK8OzgPGV7EjVPpuiz8iiQt3vd9Uc/QLSZUtkWlEuI79GfHMUydhMKzC@B@hHeQlbeHXpQHorD0hkAOgU1fHQO60ADfBgvgFKAi5oB8rl@WxFKe4xHIzOoE9VMjISD61ZbwL0aYkjKaAvLsxY2bAfBX3UgN/QmpebZ1lN@A3HDcm/uc/vou7uYCJWzh2xkhcrnlixbfopbLyEr@5SLkTvXM4G2wHb9iAlPlpAM0MRhbTQo/0D3bWTIrdlLdGVPQhJhamgzOwF5@ndHznL8IVrUddawOszBatI6JAJi2S@LvXvoFu@Qo47O@FqQwuFhtzFUGXGiYruX1wCNSM2BIhrvmKCbA2gSjzpI49kfMqpL7KvLbpNiAAjWU/eHNC4xw8wFy31pc1zYi@F1xyR@Tx/xbmxyM7QhDamcP0xAnSgwtvJPHkSLmeWLbbyNlpJzWQvbLN9kvnY1mEajJVtOhf6qzCYgK25TcIt9aVfizTk5uMVYYf6eMWoyk7bfgvLKHJ13RuHQ@muQLXjgPqqa7vjkYQ9SoAYDsfs35odYaQoUJGiUt3Cl2VNRXuATeeR0Jeu6dDBrs8nRwYRcp8dGNvfUmPbzZGXiGIH5gFCSpvydZphL5JRV0ZE7G5zdIm3AzY7dKHamM/NSJ@HF6amMB50NNI@QSaT83g8Q1Myw1Gze9X0ROZocDpqTqswbcHKZ9zyXWghhmBCJHDwyarnNU8hzC2SXUIU0U0hyyG8vKA3ldejcd/a2ucEu1QNBRl2BQdBgp2IksG3RF@l6Bhz9e/oBBPlGeGtTyOliCXJi5ZGEpJtus3QMJsZOpaqwRw7euDYFqOqR6biBVnoGifaKzr4BUnewxgBsm5begFKV4SNl1g/zk7doN9MTE7DnqUc/XNFwfMijme6ipKtkSx1CWohvvEOsYJ15OdkFAiem1Q4I2vBcRbOI3mdW8acRyjIt7bFzzVFqC@gowvMyDNEnPVDFpapGSq@A8MXVbL8BwidXrML@E1vm1NkxfOM82ox59Y/n/cvVpzz/rfz31zCRIpkNctmRUYeZiuJJccKzIw5L/GqrNIiFWrwvJ/McN4X7MNikAAQyTn1z7mLbzlA6DyDt8ufZ5ggiS5DTHIP15dD8LkZNDNJLHIZa8FdcVXnO68KroC5lX6xD/mDy7@AhdpUkpoe9jmjDoAiP91fr9nlJMptruWfrxWew06oG0yyo@Aa59tsdH0ZTGApEeF2Fqae898S3JAgxN0kahbh4wTaydeasO9JJJ2UpAiVw5zqsTRbQRmfeQLyA5UpXCq6uLg6TxMPH3HD7wlgOZWXYkGx6aDBfQ7On9HgCutpRijX0t4hzJFoZcA2IqRCzSJkdfnKfRzqquGyTH5OvtjD2K0EBLo3lzFmi/6gn5WLNddfLuIiGr1mepv5zXx6jM4M0cQIXZKLqeVFUdh59eLv/3n8a2ac2VnLfRzB7zjza2ZjM8OP8ABvz9TbTWYns43ZNu4y0xzsgeHxxd//G8rv/AngYMp0G/7srCtYG9PMTrZERb5ldjbgobC2BvX@z9/@Bm1Y4h0b3sW61PAEIVZUFNlr9ol3IV1UsZW8LV2OxQo5ZiEMtjCEvTm8oGHUZG0zT2q6jLSquAlk5CtljyKneDLMGpOpEGsylD0FrIy4QAkryDJIZULREYbthjLbQOaN0RQ/P/E3ItgB/CzNOXSV2nTjSYQmQ0u8LYIOdLhG2M/zw07@la3NO7ZsZVNSVEtI3NpJWbv5rPi/)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/rge17)

Wow, that was easy. New code fitted perfectly into existing space and no other language broke. What a stark contrast with the
previous diff.

*><> go interpreter considers the file to be single-byte encoded, while ><> and Gol><> interpreters read it as UTF-8,
so last `\` on line 1 sends *><> IP to another place on line 614.

*><> code:

```
/123nnn;
```

Answer (score 2):

## 322. [Twue](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Twue), 14640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1 1 v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v   >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9 @,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMn>MnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001 1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#  
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120. [0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897}
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=









































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::geEx Cr Uithary,85"3.c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0/a4ok: $/op>sequ+4[0]!!tfc;""[ ]5:ore>80C0 4?4在ｕ
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4Q0QYLPZ5L3U7W62SPbtK4G46AJQAKoJVKGrABJoNjskza7Wsr2zHo3skB/jK2vWs/J6IsY7sbOWd@yZCHs/Tjjmk39A@7Gx4diw/oH2nJNZhQIJgN3yOGJjY4tEVT5Pnjx58uTJd8vw@j/7WQQf9tQZzHoDZ8zGpjdmHde6MF2VPZix@4bl5fSMJGGoXbc3GZr22CtLEaYx5o0Nd8wGht2bGD2TRcBVZ3N71xqMTTfJPNNkLXPgXIJ/hjHbvGSHdtvqACQ2ds5N23ptuuCXZeyhOXgzfDNmbWc4NOyOx0auZY/JN8fYUwMs3Un7nBktb@wa7bHl2OCVZ@yZPTCGrY7BKPjINXmkAgNQ7XOKs@hTZOyx43ompOC0Tc9z0LEEjoZrOY92n3x8I7yWZh8bgNRoYE5vJK9p7Lllup2bMXT22enBwU3XDPtUcWx2cBslLct2J2PncHwTfo7t9kzbYLpaUvWbnnkg5tgcFNPF9IIX@B1YLpSmIUqtPC8ZezJsmS4QXxThpTXuqxDh1OEEZ449mDFzCsAAxy4EM8fMwtJiuXQaQ8L/idl27M4cPDiZAAfgmsPReMYUZjuCB8DLcZk3Mtqm0jEH1tAamx02sAA7pyuw8RgUODs3Z5eOCwWvcFYkRLyR2ba6FkYROfAkZLaHZmvSY85kPJoAeh7rWJ7RGkCw1ox1zK4xGYyTrAV@QDxyv@ybtkDJsnuYj@dzF4RgQxXg2G9qQBtrMGCAzjmig0l7bBs9LtEdg7ZMwtLsIKj9ObkAkjHw/NwvJryQDMZ76jo91xgCo3ZMosFnh0@Z13ZcsMEPw/JasA5M2xiz7W0W3X/yMMpqARlVtyUFJK2yK8ZYxPdkF8ZgYnpsaMwgbXsMlYs5VH5@DAmCs@hGtMyimQzT0yybZVmobEWm59IMqkQJDFBr9YwGvzzTiyyrAd/noklMp@saPWtgcig9Z9BFQAXkWD3HdHinsyyjFaNJHqJN6RRYpsjyBVbIsQK8S6ykQ0IINcu0Ug5@efgBlBJgocEvk@WpBayBLAXZYHusawytwYxDH40QfJvlNFYAiICqBpD1IkAo6Qhh8QnDG/eBuH3jAkAqA@scRYYZSA0ssRR8UltbKRJbKB95kl7fHAwwVSAWkClXZAVINQ8Zz0LKQEu9qPuZ7/Up@4RXIQ0/wLEAOS4CidNArTSSqwA/sIMo0kHm6CBgdJAZugbuOpgzCBXC5cEvD@WVz/rQ9Q7RFiQsxNWQmChUNKQBRINCYBkoijzLQhFnsIhzGQZ4AgKFPAO5UtRYMcuKBQbkKqUZkF4DZLD8NZBnGiChITAoVg3KVQNENGAYDYBqmRyTQnTVMugPcTMQF0igZSFOFsxQLloefxAPCl6DJDVIU9dLc/YC3PQcZDKXIb7T81B4BfADYumAqw7cogO2ehH8MW4RCFdEtiz4hDAGo76BtIASQGYGVgOC5AAngg3hwawXMpylKHTLHFtt6VqCmsVbwbDU8SUISgGQKMxg2IgCA865JxZIwTgIpUWBNfHMAXARyJG2AWZkW6jxKD18ONZYRVkLTZXpXGBjSiJgIRmPxETLxZYUZFbHdF2GYaHB9ZIkULxJyzNfTbC9nePVBQllgnDtGtYgQICqjjGmtgC@UQ/Smy2i3XWdIdWvIQqMgeOMVoheEE@XCOgT59Kcoz6XXsZoNACZDu4mEGJiDACZS4N0AlIZwqlyhCASxmv3LQBISYFstVyzTbQXWYfYGZDCiyiWmV67l0EoD0JNQ4aNHBCsHsaxJ4NBGZo8s80ytVTHvEihC28@FpsNxMFvUKBNFCBaBrTn1KAiFgGke7pKTdWpX7KeM1zMGhcvh0HW@xY2A4NLYwal1wXJYk6NIWgdDJt2GxrvIXAML0EsCY83Poes49jRcQDl0oUmFjId5ARADogmY2togk7mQBQs8SwhjcKNMGvNgJWJWlmVVDKOyQ1CqdJNQnGHbMiBVxZo3DqTNlIN07Zs4iBoFDxqsWoAlyueKhqgyrmm0eHBUMNAjEI6ErR4JhBdqANtAoRaiml7oPF4KrNQNQSG7zld4DFqpkHdgKjzdNqUd8x54DRV26pElEa@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@L7Zf0HSORo4LNYMLnRlKMl5kIe5yeF8lFjQRceg7L7ao0FJEsZ0fj3m/azSAvhBVMaypoE8aIClAiPFeAMg8h6cYQphqPcES@F2SxOfMBE2obZuokhrujAOB7EGrDAnNmOW6IAYvsG3gTY/fhqjEp9AUGJ0OSlYkB9X7m4mryNF7k5Y1vdnVaKOj@tKTLgyXdbGX4YKuAZUoFu160XiF3ClmyEtOOaNxiqLytwwBKZAKRR7rQscFGoIDEDQnM7sdkxeqmJxk8mTcLcpxMGBErpqxrxqj8U3sXoIbMs3wHOo12SqsB622osBbQTfCBD1SKnoYLqgXUAlByy6VOi2DvQHp4TJlukexUS2kr6Zmg7RMuxOkJQiBuITzq/IkPLdNBiXUqmEOMDjlnBqJBQK@JyUoogwOqZRoP9GBlDzuR@oMd5zYNETAYlwDibOrQEWHBiBGyFigc1hta9wUWsq9e76@slGtArOBEgVisxMPK/f@WIoKkhoCq6SEiETUsXMyxroRi0N@MfA1xwa0JeDUao1djfsu1DiyX0sQCMgq2cjJPmFFOT@xziedmwVtoyMGkrHWga5ktcdyRYLGn9eG6jqqRheoCsp/FKmKzIvxCfQt5iVXLFBZBHNND7XeqkAlVMIxxEDw6lIS8ajCbc7Qe7P2QKgE3ASVnUujFqB/LnrrgSBKCp3Ar7S3aioHgtWBw2FPd08/qYq6yD1TLcsuLzgMnLYxIOdNDC77cR8dPjjePf56cwmMgdUq33RIWdliHpvayVTp2ZNUVtXLm2EYc8APm@thY8TFMLIkvJniTEOq0qwNjcvUJ@fR8ac3SQKaEJKDUgAz/m6oNDwMKF1Sy/D6Nxph1kskIMkgih@WKYfMhxkYEHX0N3x8nk5ev8bCu4nUSLgjZoOJwQH4jqlD24@noucNBcz3anV5i0hxQQu1bBwDnZvCIX18Pkat@SYypEqHWObjo4P94yqB7RveuTkYKBQk5Y1BlzLcjgo8P5h0TGlZGBB/YGqzhDpHHPVpwnUpgdvtBQLPy5atgA8AsIujOkwZDP2seX3Afe9m3shVaQccQHaCcFOvDOtD7Q9FNIQHNnFt7Okua0XJY95YBU5LW6zAd7HZaudyZiFbCjdb7XmanTDQISnFluPrjS54nXsKuqhzLVKo1QL9k0e3EPdIiYSugOJj5g2YSml5Awl7L4rFol5qD3pozsBUn5PEk5kcT6Wi/uCn2vaozxkKvz@1xrF0nH@1OISF1Hd3D/WHfmAxUEcDGNRpwC44tkxuFycb2h7wiO0MnJ7DtiAO1w79BEFtWpnN3Z5j3yohAx0xqxGcvQD5i@M1xgjaGus1dRwpVri7ymc@DNu7BCmt5TNIJKIQgUpRePWlcWEAueb5Pjn8xj40IlounQ7MaXqABKE4RC40tUOu5MAUSEgV@CzNYDCTcau2@x5KaCoBMy0EXRBxd@691JEkpppaGn4pSl91blH8pTO7wVrgwlkLDCGSHT55@ujwyf7j3c/Pxnout2DPpkt5IByk1wJdSO1zumFt3eJVE7OF4CJQN1ysXiAFJtBB8YfEJ54LglvFICpHYAXX8Dmg2Fedvh314jczc4m@yku7zVnoMVY@HlREhI52Z4CdEZdPnWF7jvzTH49HXjmVglren7RU6LSmXradgdFLUTxoGAaDlIZdl8MjHNfwlsUAZLyZyWPwMS1QHWY0cGgMhg50Xmg6DkUDi3HwNFg1sHp96AvjnJ3pxtWAgyk3qQ70EKCvnAryRgKYbEBb8fXLSeas/RVNL3K@1tJ6NiX7wRaqP4Td6JrQdYpBawWkiN@wsrN7Z/fYDKQ0QroJJMLULTFtg23BgIEiSYOl2M/3iUPSAodJUVYQjV5NcBAXpFQql84WtHwuBd0y6KaBzqrgUJsyNMbtvjJ2FICnOF0aNwhxYddrG3ZX3RIGH1nQ@z6CrGbqX5yd2Q1Q0M/uEW44GVafNepaI15ht6NsifDxCnDvQvaQd30H4F0yAmvSl62QZx3jtjjrGFS7Oiw1Ho5Em6OM2ONdUKReOyCvO2a47mGEVNgztbUQNoWB36aWDAgNMKqEL6RUCioUtLTAeinESwGlF9VD4ByQW6EIbD6awfPBp6BDcgQ73cj3lhP1aKwe9RocJPVGQEQaY26jlPZwfHAMrWPA@SiloXBRSLNLM4rD54bHBykhkph49ONDXy2AQIPxwUC0HUy4AhNQLOqeg@QAvsLR0v58lBE7/cBpkCDhhIMPoEHYNGnQAzkDkXlGdnlGeErkspilc9u5tBFay2RFpWWN@Ri/M3FxQs/qhPMGwTM6DwPQKHMhuU4zfy2zzUdZeWTKBXQCDTY0hw4OJYB2RaLApCwYfNYQ@4IeDlRDtUorOHEC8BV2fw@kWNvk40XKEDtRwFL7LDp2U7vKN1KG8hq4eY1uhZnfDU9iU6Gf@gSgkchgFptGScQIKGknzpACPafxFvR84Ku70mg27kOOgcNko@qMTPtmn4/3CGPxCs21RqMg8C07dhXd2NiIlqO1aBJMO2DaRtMOmhJg2iGTQiYMp6KJYiTJhL51ioFujeh13Yc8jTeQB6aoOby2RjGjXi5nGkmjromvjt84FAVQHkIr@AE40Xi1isZ4XK5d4lQN6O@hvO8h75y0XWskSPBVUAi4XdAgQ0SA7j1q865Zwb7peooMqy50Gk1UMWNu9KyePmucXZ11EmfX0STGjleMKvQPQXiNY0O15zqTEShu9WxZAdkWr2fKjUqrGk1Ht2KxojKAhIx4/KNiPGFwWseiJvBU7OwsCiQV1Km3@y7Bmyb1eDwgFODRtaCXMRjEoupVEdJvxRvxRBTixqNJEMvVaBTo0kYieJRpHBHgTHRgTYGUUDGhiQvPKZCApDkprK7fMEf9mRsOEIy6gZaNI@jzCXmoDCTFw1LyNY8fVugWevq@3svDgXKLg3eoL41mXLpLHNOz1MLiEL/dvVC6Q2dspD5TodOkhprL6EY0pSjQEpIPh0TZfmx5WIUN23QmXnikcekAKKYOrqf9CQhLf@VMErjKGklmu@@w6OZ9gM6CaR5sSnDGSuHzXj6ATluFHwpR1EpwsgS0C1pSYoFcxOUmfFRGIyS46PHH5nP50Ss1SK1CcVgaE7J6tuOaCpAEYki0AISWC0k1JlaVHNLI1615CeFLTRp2vC0TJOLBwDGItlxch@aDRsNQfOifQ5RjsyMNQH50QTyqvCxcs5Pakmhy1nH70EJAblAS60FpDYVHyvFGHXU8hahSDBvcsCfv3YHSeck6uq7n27lu2fdDrgBi96GQsFdqQxfX91I08IyLQt7nw0J@H/3J0cN9PnZCjS02rziO1hw6nQnolaLfdGzavSTbB36ybGdoARn8@K/PB8eOM@a9fLCsGpnhnWZrOBkYNOZzc1hmbby203IGNBS0Luo8/MT1jIHBB6F8393PHoOu/@z0pKqWQ4FSxsVwbdo4Drk8WU7Pw/CcI02z@tNDHmdMeTMnY7vlL0hDMSM88ugxEcvRoIx89wK6@1UK51CEexHdh7gUDXRlMYpA1sBRBCxRQFyehqt6hOOVlr5G95V9sCCcRuG44jjH9krTyf1i3O0uOGfI@VxB0TSYO2fJmS9TW@gjhlHK8UC4Zm0hTBhQnsIES9duhhPCK1hi0DcH/gziMSgmOEsGbfsA1Sfom6AmztePmaBIj3AyhCQ0TrGxNuia3q1hC6hTI4WHliIbVE@gDUuh5iJtppgY4q5QTbEdMTXpcenpQNeeRk@2a3zCGrtOLu@1pfjg@2YTQGzXKv5qolXBMKVoNAhGUAk3iEHZpGn7W1kNFmF4NKYuUZSK5KWg1zDV08rZtLDfSHlEhC6Tz86mH6X1z6Hzgeu@Nu@lemYFk1tJLbLzceh2H8QGS0wXSQblMLG7zqCj8EkvKH/Gu0tYEGKpQbDyjAQ@uFiuv@jMwkUsYnEgiMvQerVbcG8UXe12gNAKtwAQ1IYr9uY8efGG1aEFu1C90cAaN9i1Onaafcz8eOLaN9fCcZXSdY2ZJ4mVKlW2e/zxZ/V0g0OQhgZOZBV5aU39pZSgB4PegytWwYTrbcbWmBp2WlhgYX41FZCa0pwHoA8weAIVFiQkcoSovzHfzPPSNaHjGTMRc282TDIzfq12B8Z4bNqct/hs4mpy82kfkUyVkt8RcwhllqaJFlA0LfQDFCvs5PTh/vGxChzqxaL7OCFThmpntPugb6zKtE/JcObL7KNOlH2EceLYC5egSkFnoiniA/NWgLmhOwGpoyjomW4MHOM4l9IGZ5q@oohc4RIEwlVT7THRKAAWM@OQJwJWXor/M5v3nASeZRZlCaIkkDt2rwy0teLqxLZeqR60G6SGQpAo73vSMtnqZozE16YWJ/5xrSHOBUOXibRAyEO9zjZAulFomVXfsi/qaaXUSGyyRqPCZ/ghIur0tOxWLOE0BD35dBgJSIHzoeiVdW8s5PVToJFbjMXx04BnJcG3gKw7ac1u11J5U5fjAbLKa3DgnvJNJJcsNOUo@kubSITQSqjFFU2L66VC2XpGnewbC8QhOz4CQX5wGjLGc8k2qkyLx33MOKDnhotd5zJ76nie1RrQCtbuwOIrwYLGuiwIIyD5lAknV8GKQXTD@gz1DAtjvmyZLwYWlCB/amigJ4U5I4dYnF0hMYmUOlKRvXmDDjLb1BmxgYyrhjl9r/0@LcjHRw4g@0isgg7rHCQ0xPIUFB1nkux33hbnf9GHdwxSFzd0XuVCDsfjOqdlnzs0ixSYmmlVy6GeGcQeng9ux@xaXp9eC0EDHHhYfRV23rDVpdeSADSZIqbpyYGG6YWGDcVppI7pQyP2S1JeXJqykGzL7E7sHs1popkpr@4IqZSKFLjbalmrggIRcLWZ/10SDGQl1jxdzaqaX3twgAeaRZCfvE80z/rNVU1sge7QSI0hlvj@5292gP63S6cP7RWOZwaGJmgKWFJKd2VhiahoodfyguXD7pOBZRBhyHQXyLbhQpaMQWBYDpqm9hUF9I0hTlSIEgfexBfoomvYjGPO5xn97/JElk3V2SC326vC3ljlxZOiSSXoLnaICFznskyKREKWF4I55RM7oY47Cty7kfKXYjFiZl7u/cl4wt@gDt9ZiNYIf@vqpgiZzhktzYQOqdGyzDVF7hrnk46jjM57gVqcXxJ2nnuaWVZAKxGTzE00Ls8@z6Br9aC597@rgs3b19Qlfe7iCs@eeCOlRX37DrdRRRiuScEd8PeqIJbYrRQYVlPNGtDrPTlRQAdGEWssUriCVQkRzbpB5oHRmqEq1P9wLgvWK4DEqbYTiXRmxYT1aLQ6PvZPKX6ptDz2VG1zeiwbeUjxVbIKH5ujDIt1s3eUKjRX1tAYKHonZFwpzJctd7gVNJgppTjmBc4TXSwtuTn1sUFqTwaGOzetYfE5Hv7kxKpxbtFsiLrcdgaWhxV6sEpq@mvu5mnhOmV6hdZVWMso2YGOKLbjSmBaLgWc9hjXoq5gq/eQaXwNKK60DfGJ6qwiVtu5xN9KDaIPnWH@Xt6ovV6K1XvIJ2XQHhjQlK9sERZGHXFU8w5evbQ8k17LCXu@FNFxe7DUfbEW@OOJ4fHBuzjbswaOx07ovY5APReowN/LeTpMS8uwFRplD5vXiCF/8cS8QI1Bzxnki72UAa@VpT5xuyj6xfd9hVwgpDTtDiHla0COrYnvStF@nnLP7yog2v/l4sLZkHFNK7tMUolJndW5g74Bzgguz9lBukgx1RQfQ1yRMM7lXBoz//tztB6rSOu3HqMZadSg4GGEUhEMY5dr2T9Patn1qXXeTyjdAlu4KxOhwj0fmNBe0ftWkTI9rX1gDC2dfn8R1R1MzIm5tK9x1Hpp4lbiNf2M90cqLbKxKaYAcNYB97wEoV6LzuF7YY1NNdrWChMDeu3m3drMolAbgQI@wt7zUzA8RcPtGD17Mloo1YUOmn28nmT9kV@lnc4CdujzoXKoeIeytKCieyb91naaeCcPV55Vs@l0WugwoamcBcu6zlQmiPvS4u@FhMllnvI8LE7fuSHj8jSILOG1jStFkL6qb0@BS6WUbdnmeIbv95SmLccZfEhJgVDtWKiNgXJJa3jXldgtdUfsTmHz0QsPxzxa3VXjFry1Ed1LoA/2m9cVeniu6b1KU8HZ1CHOdC1a14/ghGau7koFt3TjsBBf1TtYrUuKARFNLaqFtbWOa6hOyxwY/DPNZ9fBK6mZtfAWhYaYBcZZYz5XPJ/jj9wQSqMZEMvqQEelbw5Nsq5R9I3Oy4nnf1YGmjr4W@U9Nc12arpvtlcFGFkgF2x8L0xOh5SlsWNDF2uMCwixqzLAJarCdZUE9qcTlxL5cGj0TH5OxTpJOR@zwGU6vGc3Ny4fvSjzpTltiDYfYV7NElCpzs2Z53@XAnw8a0O5ToZ3j7jdqPxtHAZ9j9q@am3s7SbW7jt9u2/2@YL0wLaqcgA/jvm5IutQB6x7fVwjNxotrJ0P03PgDAbvQ08UjVxQOk53KU77uKsWt4R9ENyZ0QIP8blz/M4Yc9mBhpW1pm9OoF3ynLEzMhWyrQo6wLEe/l4lQ/3Z7593EGltVx8o4n9/Xvh39i17hjMejejTHA0mHr0oqkKboe/Sm7p8zQuttnTcnvraGbZU4aiKBTE06b5cxLSscbuPm9A5Z5s9p9XuW3ch3TKNsW2dp/xRH259r74rUsZiykN0VgcWkNedqcgv1bD/CX4OVxW6GEDizVpgWKOvLBuko/3eysg4b3t8QBRNrIxjwqHayHeFl2k7ffnVxBrPgYYWSQUjvHxmAg2rcBfLMlZqVrT5Yi6GxXKNlVxKSjoq5IqZBoVHWzm@tLCALlTFMhn@WoVQOJeEUWjBy4eQWywqogFCKzR0C@4L/LWwGmppI2f3Jz3vtsDkI/YdUNHwtXrYghZJh0atoc0ybPFZRWZ9kMLdk/Btgs41MddOq@TWzqtQOG2gGI4FnyZ8oOgmK8fQBtbI42@mdFfOxolFUtAXvzllyGkzW96ZFgXTMbt8FgRNd6mIQ4fmaUEHUdo4p4@D6CjMueLFBZft9ECoKwM2D@yHXaW2LF1/tLz4gzZT@fyJ2TNwEfcja4yrQJdwBbHssnVLd8L@2sTwrK9NIGermA2PguAzkW74zAC0LYH32OhZ7U8WCiJAUhBYLCHlnwX2R6fbZXHZtzxcQxUY1gxMIctxJkaua0K/YUnIm0P3wSkY8wrE91cuDb1seN0ZzXAb2oxM60bWrTGNsorvqq7jqtVla5G4nAxHE098luNAq7TCo9DDc3L3Li0ArrwC0cr6xmC8fKQ6NOQKWphoFOfGVdr4N6yB02PfKKYZKG2ghKFyvoRxHkDz/BSXBrn2Ek6ktN9z5hMHOhSXZ@wVlK2ZYYplW@P1oznjMS4T8r@YGd5y4NaH1CN8q/c/FIJyupwij@7W9ed7nu9o34HzTpyJ2zbRGBxkEu4WiFTNPX9ZM24VcfAglstwL23t7A00h449GSvuxF7bKuTXtgplNi3mQ2zAYl/bf/wsHuYGWgZ@lxZqQudv4g1mc9PKNQM3mMyyQRFbLUcXQ/t9iYf83KVjWoN8R5xdPByqTeL6obOsv/N05prj9@4wgfCfDB@abZw5vDPtJ85jx3agNRqBoBwem/wwgYW1HssjYrRHuF0e6NO5M5kTAruiEeLahjEyW1C@g7npfdoiDvihMTZWNEU0Nkj9v8B0J69Yg5bpvqRBv5B5VZd2EaFPzCn1LVYzDK@Dyrjd5ioxjsct1JGFGRtv5Dg2f5O0TcNHe7xeqkBTQK/3nytXcYX/wrjA0v7ZYlaPLvhCEbPDT7tYlVfXbDkD/l6zLMm2@LIAw7VML/UID08gt3yWKaB9eWtlSGGtDJl3jUCTvTA8mqdf3tWYg9SmH7AKqG@4bQdnwoRhzQKd0IkHd4jpYNMAXzvQAsJPQWIZ7Yk4e/EutAbD1pBeKzsModI8Nlu43ahFx4SMjentwuQjQ@KMhNCiruBkAV9cYaXOs9hT6I3E7262FvpRi1S1RvQiSb1yupzW6yi2ZbZfGzhq5hC95mPTC/6Q59QTMq4Yqw5VIxpFThm0hX5pTVpcvQYKzcBUxn0X@vyp8brhbf/8liXzIZOhiZPMi7MwK1VXx@tTZp3l8@mBcHVNRZwdCLIkOEeQ64fK7krNE8HD/9GDr6agEW7ms/6ZJiC67p7BB@Qnri0@78OBTx1v3LWmR4A37jtYJU4wWzmIAh9eM9C0tSoTUHr2ZMBHH3qhpVfDDnXHFDrDVlEGJK7HpmLaFwqdMDe9nSOH7yZL7eJhqGOzo4gDFnCmQXnkbywLgonvkgnUsGzE9Z5aihN2ms@KFaDLiHvpSwbQt5yxMvLomxp5Tw8fHZ2qI09b2j7t9nE/xi09buHEBr2YDg1JvTTc0HwnX5HWsbxx6sGJpuw9OlQxwAp68xkNBT44M7fwWTnuKY4eNVLGyl4Q@prj5QriJ6ePHyXmez9ZbK/vOkMzHvbeOzlJ4t6Wr54s9Q7HPoDa0XWmK6Mf7mtafAn7PrNpdnCV9FyS0ipIpyb0RoEZP@EHvtypXLWdkdk5nY3Mz6DxRAnuvWfy@ZWZfGJcWD2shay0klBUUVlJzWfjocXZ0Nk23eC7qjzPrRFKyzZ9UvyzcjkKag6ZlJtZrj2sm/G/qcWwtFiJ8GGRtPRtbh1bCtSMXh9NKcP7hyKmadoqOp8YXShXlltZWIsBls0PD5yL95hKNkXnRQmclDFwlWLduZS8oAxBdKfwhcPzwhGMrZXLYNYBCJzzSyv8pWnPDFuhuax16kUZYuOitrVBvmG@x4RUsMLnAg@EXjrHF6yqZ7E2GeN3JHzqhqLs7T04vCvCsaDl@lAfP3nGnhoenm6yPmAYY/M9MJ5rRi8VHLfCo/VWTqd2XAClr4XXGy2vz2V2Yrgdx55N756Eo82t2LTTYcUBLLRRIHNgTa1lbVWbj2s9Xb7M6K60@T4OZ7agB4dPvRGA3n3nn2taOk1nGuFXS3PrHSXjV3AWQ5Mxw4Pywl6nh4FoaKPeooJDfGlv9JE5xeUofDR4Wad@afuWX9P2FeKrm5N1fsU1ftk16d3yQ0eWUdPaGoC5NX4spwbej5zBZd9R9wzX9N6zTEKorctSaU2WSiE5/bqYxuFQmmIU5tXKPu5jEJ@lfHtqjt3sqO@0rOwdudnt4omW7DEeyH5nJcMNZbT4peeIPSHcvhyHy8laCcV3hB1P7PAZxV5SnDLBN3LyrXWe6h8kHYvZiUQ8vnhXQXgjId9ChyfZ8d1vEPbNG7YhNrmBR7DvT2ytwwOvQOM2cUOqRCBwx2PMrla1XInt4I0BZWhP45QiOtGxQn5adbZ5JXaslcvaNe7ak8syEzsKg1NC@UmXABfP6IM8MeVcY5tj8Nn097sxOqudvWGko4NSoOXSYFNT4Q3IFbEREFDavHp6@HT/5HT39NlJPd24luNiuyvHzbYhNX8j9EeZjgx5F2SDus/PvaUNswNIjs6RR93e8/PFIGc3slZdyNo8U/IOxtm8su1UivZ9ppRrwE@ReWrkCw05OnHYfo6pfMS23TLfLjkgksqbHLRMaUKZlVl6WcIjA3h20xb@N2@yIF@WyaAvT1gcVQos2XOcjkjRM9ndj5/iwe7ho2fH@8xHcM40l1Zn3K@WcvwkW2wfFRPKqWvREpIqi4ooUSirajV6EAXCRNUoK9NuWzpFFvgcgvnUwX26IvYWi20SfKBgNCiU1H/@Zuo6quJqyDiEjfpIRZmgPAZgp7iD7s9/3OGnrPvnZvhXtrhDagzofAJJ7I5dsTcWKUoVc7T64hY61Zy2wQbHqc8vw5HokH3gyks68urGcUhxOqGE38IjTqvyEyIG8U9mxmE1PHnK9diFhXtgOQ5dPAhqkZVxJp4OP1PZLt5KAzzPDDrpH1Cf2GN@2Io4miECfKQGAiXJNglZfi@AHAoY3d4AVm6ZPctmng19FXNcZi@Bz3Doqsw3YitKLXorig@aX0ek9MfDQSjgrZOjvNTZOPXuV7@b6lUYmKfpB2D7ZWHrgvlXuPmLFJb17dOl5umHkcAT4QTWPPGA5kjv0AU8Nt/wPicWHoLlS0pmDaFoLojSGJynwN8KCNg5nFj9MygoYDEoJbHRnadnuo0YHklXTqWQjbCtU2lxrznlK21uHE2Xz@WzWgqQVC58gHSWdA93EXKA8XgZGF@6sEbVFy1gr@1tJqPqa1bzFV6aqU37i4z8IkB0E8JKl31Ers4gDkSZxwC/mogGzUlCi2NUlEdRLYqiqONAO0P@2B6h3RaEkFkMiMVpZOLhxFO8iWnszvwjFlt4u1HonoFNAUjRoJUhU1yWxN7sJ84YWGZhVzrfm40rzXibhmeXefymMTrZEHlQvV2b5lsK/QsNRP1Ssd5zUJn0zeYxXLbycwRxgiDK8jKWrX/BzsZndiPFeZMBm/5QsGyYmW0w/1Kqt4Jneb53b59rF7t5Kh0Si90/sR3U8Q8gMyymp/RMSsvH51nKZpdmSeRIJAPZwdM23kByIJpATLRN66Uz8nb39g@/evT05NbZbRQyejMYSPLaduJMUZP1RmCIhrO1WCQPDlInjx8c@AUxRzofksCgvYicaOtyMu@6I8j5UvCbWVuG4c3crcb4Od8vehPfjL4ONYp0Cw8t/QHp0nJM5YA2VdxMXC8uo1Yutw6lObxUCPQe3xF3C9VY/Oq63tiundmR6G1OWFIRvoioW1gJwHTmbW2mkNlvZw4zFtwIeIr3GHnhuphZXhflzQweIYR7csfO@fzwJOEQ8gjl108GRKSkpvygK2vfEde650d86fzGQn7YUPiIlRDC@fQ6iodAnfqXH6IUmR9QKM7m60MHemC1JP9oG35Gn3@UWHA8Hz@WJhaXxDH3POGYuA5xWp6qtPYiFkdpR7CSbN1xfz68uAQVGvW1pxPo1jx1RvzYY5pje2j6pmMHxO/DCZ@sN9lXJ0MI16XPsUnjnSC5FYgMlIwGqHL9CaSEOO1vmsDzFCG9Op75JzKuDju52DSu9s1px@qBbI/FkyDRPtK0BgtOBMRM0wmAdlSmMpuXwtqq@DHucwyT/YOOhZzOETDqhmrZHXMai15G4@UGpI/u0cvnF9G4vIyX6HhKcV5j5@Y5lQH6BW29JDHGonb6h0Aukxal0m0pAW43AfMDlvw7V0olte9JdHVWFXXxk7H7CIygRsS6Q2PEYhObH0KlMrLGzmJ2kk7tUWr8HDubJRLURYIPeaiMYnbJxNvvmGHPWCxVBSZAV8/u4Oe1NWJ1TVUbYKZE4mwT70LaA40LD3SJS9CrhShlAltFFoKOA2DEK4nKGRzioL@E5@y4dJTXEm@6GoaGhRykCeWa1e6x0JVWi5qjXCqVRYEuSsUSA@67LQ7VFIC9Jed8XR6oKw6MAJpBh1aVInNBflviRSjdCEfkE3HSBKATCZ096R9AwQDW/GTIdt/FX2zfhrqCZ@aUn50eNIvxlMyCEyt6rtXBYUt@fHLQaRMXXkA1TS0EjVZ4H@1jjIZHkTX5kRh4UtYBVRj5hkiNhMlw85LXOW9q2lquFxFFKUDILDYAYltP0weHZ@75E8hL/JYL@5/9DK@RlWObO/lMc3CRiObSFXhplRzLsY82zxRls65p2XT1/qZhjF@dycxIZbceXpj9buuwlzqTZZZh2VRqK3qw9dTS81@8ml5ntOKr85GWr6uvpg25WE2eN6bs6dPP3zbfxuXpxUw@izFWiDC2d/RG1rLYWY2UC6zE8LfwvMYX3fK49LnVS5ejMoucneH1sHJBTqXq0Qb8k9cLeHigek2tqTuNt2/j9QLkaTpjZxG8cpEd3Udv6ifRSJOux08sy0qxs5HX6cDP6bMGvzc4wp9EIqYw4aDUuVtlOO2S23TX7PUm@8aMu1uRCX4OxiLu4288f/4cDc/pYa@PIwI2h@inUW4auQjT0/qf/2TjOnn1tLn9598apswN/Bzh57vXj9F8ouU@2tj46MGDbDYJtOHmp994@vXd3d3sw2TuaT23k1XSG9t/9qcbG7q@rac2Gp6nNaL18/PPZT2dldU//1G0@fTp1zyvlvk/vvm2puGrAK8LLBl8MkwDI76L8NNQxzpnr@E57zL8J/PrTshsoLnVfc0iryPA5VpkRn/NSFBmG0yr7RT@y/ePXkXGkZqeeu7Cdxx5FckXI9wIBrBlfNtFpBbZxmD568gsVa1WwVj4L/8W4te@CnDQZ7YNr1rOh5WfRWpKlaK8idTyYNB0HdL9v775zRDzcDFRJTXOf@6zOjxytqDLOw14tujZlvCcMCWdSt3gP614T7vHmD3uj00HPxb/2CYe2KxUoNd9XE8kEg1VgUdtUqSUpulnIADYAmvReAtRSVi5Cwu7BXwiXMDveYR4CpiK@IqbhQOxGnd4fjPc8yVP5fk/9nMsRfIb982HtRqIwkwts1VL0LNxVi5z8qdYoSg7zn2ZbUGZpen1CN5Ir5rM0kVdTiaT95GSOtJU0QX9ItEzORqJvJiT1KdshM1tLOxEbyoINg@zKhxjy8Pt4/MX/@tf/OAvvk9/P6Dff8Aj1eyO1U1tMao5FzX@sFpNrrny1RlZIMPpcrFcTDWvz2JbIKkax0xLf/wmmstET7CVoOcs7o9wRoKnVsMX/Qsbmeh7w0341AILhZhHWR8OOY3ShSZYrDxT6heATW2eo1tPid2HUpL1Qklu1PScflST05rMy62/6TFHiIPIDjwb8Ef/8ATWDRxF3iC3Dd@HQt1@NpZhwMm7/pEi9XqqYTZAkWVBNu5vlDeK5XxZTzVXwUXQlaWpgby70NqtVut1u2XA0zLahjY2JvfVglpU9W1jasyMcWvSmrbG7Ulb06TI2/oGO@a1oMES/nOWuPN5pqpNYSSDgz9FcaYRKfKP8NQkFrmCp/F2q/4WmFokXRc1OLGtNGoJgRF81Ob9RkK5vq6rXyQqFfG/XQuMFXq4CTLSuFaU7S8AVv02VA6U3mrzi20Am9iub1edPfqpTSS@0viiVt9ejCui37@fQOl7HwDUNhssmnWieec@iycSm4qyUV@ZBwDcAL1lexuK9nr7unZd376@3t6G/216X4svuF5v3/qnz/xZEWbu38AKdVZP1c5SZ4KhGmBXUzV0UVNnYKjBF8JBAyVFQGWZSpEtthUZMa2QARMzy9qWnknlph/l90FVqjcU7NtUlbqWzzUULsNeqKys8BPatWI@rqKQajrdJm6qVNkLKfLi3Zf/M/7O3n35B6gBgIZWkiKpLew4lHj/AV6Pbfb48WP8PbZt@IffY/7Y6IIOj@3aY5t8uQMZHvuhhDN3WaiUKDiYrBfzcjOhzXQW2ZbzBRQdv3DriUaj/@SFXipEeTcb9yG@8MDxF5Y9/@QXVj1S5E0JhUHbYzx7UgRKJKIoNSlS2x7iyjMcuVawk/BZ9XPl2a6CvVpjTHMRbd5jqx7uV0ulGh9033xKLLT1cAveGvzvb3ge3rqJyVzhq/UK/x69xr9XY/w7bePf8Sv8Y6ev8e94jH/scQv/nnr4d/oK/3Zb@Hc6xL8Hr/Dv8Rj/nvXwT4pUQb3f3EkP0u20dq6dg8FiaZel@@m@1tGoPUqbLD1Lz1h66GgdMJnwlwaTle6ydI@l7bQNwcAXTGOWHqOpC58e/HUBkAt/Fq5sONfSbQYJDbClouubKIF0@g3I@viZVIeeq/zCBG1c1dS0mrcaeO59XW7opSJTsczUZv3FWbSBB6rqpSxrzcyNsxcs4oEmX4mkzs5SfEyC6dkKHpF/fd1s7j952GymUM6dPXaO5v9HR8Owde3/8Mh5fOQMHfg/Ojp6zMxa4n5CuQ9PtZbYFp@dSK2yc1ZWUCj4ciiS2t45q2UUNOcTqIKgW@IDnzlE@NY2zqQoAwXpskJqWOXyonJZIUNgBUOzEgQQwbgBHCtCfQOXiq/HXcJzcUmO@ELj5fOzwMQNqeeXZ9gdgX5m8A96btj6X@Hf@n/X/@NnLFZvgFoVu7rejtETx794/Or66lq8a/FYTFhi2/CHDmDHKFfXNTRSoCsw1WPxRvz6mrvBOxbf5gBrmMZ2jSLPA4IIiARpUrr8Ffuv@8W0xXOGR68b8wUCZ2fTdDpeaflHPePkmPGG5mnjFbq4Z7NV1xp/9iM60HsnToFy2UpF22Lcomf1SiXr2wrFSqXoWzZjsdLtp5be0fKgV2Wz8XilApYdH2warAHYIoD1LTmAanpGm@p9JXJ1eERHXYOYyEXimCMuGGJpOhEfL1eJymX53r2YuLR1Zzd@755eSr95E7iMRuCkLTg1mx3LbTbRPfPmjdyUacK@lAN7uvjmjZYuJbRo3HFjT/BWHkgqpmjsI71GqZYcF0hRAG@mpfQ5Hn3DM8ZjN/baGiVlXKflyXG6NCOddtyz6E@/961vnUWrVVmRyTWrIQBMheW2t/PZWi2fBXO@CLSSN6/4/TG9REmLX2@mZE4PJm9GI8JLKxbiXDpG0R9aTbZTgyru4XN1HaFyZ9lcPAbiNQ5q3HUE/7izVipx92w@VkyUxF91I14D/YL/Ya84k8huFbbuNxj9TZc@KJIrV2ZVu65emWUcXbyutMWFiLit07x3L1MCmhbTlTOp2Xy4e7rbbFZlWcZGEV7oSMJdwnuYRm60TgWeKzXqmLvGWTRartwn5tCKORaJVkQ4JQqtBCuWiAiS1cU9257HJE2MOWxIOn3xJYlRpw1wjGCrPP89fbS7t3@a1LdBX9IPdveS@smzBxENrbm5nbwzaD/e33149AwiPH20v3uy//HhZ/vPnoK7xy7njy@BxXv@DZuW2C/Zc@ml@9owTcOcmGbzcjK5fMVeWlbTAsIOJpZlOT2XeWbTNM0RBPOfCvzalme8fGm4I3rYux9@590P/5t3v/u9d7/7nXe/@4OffvmD78Dvx/D7Hv9@79@Ucvj@6Zf//Pfe/c7vguN/gN8fw@8nP/3yN77Jf2T/E/j9p5Dbn4hfKBz/SQDrl3/65fd/9NMvf@U34fcvxe83b/9@9SfLfz/49uofxvv@760P871/C7/f57D8sN/7He6G31vhf4eH@5XffPfr/47//5n4Q@Pvvvv1P8GXsPyz3/yz//TuW/9e14t/9q/fffv77779rXff/u67b/9T/d1v/GstHX793rsf/OFf/9Hv//Uf/Q/0/2N6//77/L/7zX/2l//LX/5vf/lH4vcT@P07MP3kL/89MOzf/eEP8f/7f/h3f/xD/P@f/tXf/eGv/d0v/49k@C1u@L//5b/h77/51f/4t7/93b/@yTf/9td@8re/9Yd//b//yv/5G//xb/7bP/ib//5b6PhbP/nrP/7lv/rWd/7q2//ir7715Yr3d9a@v3wP9y//EVzeH8/3gfM@@fpQly9/Lnz@IdSYpwJ8Atz9S@9@4xeBwX@dsXff@TEuTobfiv8f6xqF@TG3/X/AoN/OM/qkwQS/X3v3ne8hif47IBH8B/T6bmBZ8OGW784tQNbfXhLpl3765b/4EdkiZrlGI8nYjhb1YmIL@hpbpZJoS8UgM0T5xUVoAQCR0ndRQi34fRdl27sffvPdj/7pux/@1rsf/jK2Ykq2lNxNKtr64S9o@pTce4TDgPn3CYcBP8f0EzQyqyQ@Bxv7XHh@/vnnUvNNClfB338Drp@TE38Y98JV8sLL90N3XDbP3rCwWRjTwrgpXIOUCQtMNUEawJavnuQybJoQCE1x3A@/4A6BpltknOKbXNF7KuFr/j83TiWWwDD8wXuDfCMZRDyRBDdKOUgmMZ365CJ9iXEdZYu70JwVpZstMczBdJqYQkcUDJBCArweJFi1Wk1gxCrHB6wctVqRESqJRBXyjbF5nGSziCCmDwgKxKwmjllzqzrlERMIr@aTIyGh07Gs6XKiWH0ICVanDxnCQuAE9sWLaq1YndYQ3FtOj8Q08YBwQmDVxLT2FuxVgpnAgaqHbwGVYjWRqBUxQcwkL55kkxdSjjJHeU@whCgD@OIw8M59xj6StaLM5082kGA8NL4T89A7NKG3A/5niS2RHfr3jfTbIoJvUFIiFcb9d0hD3OFKIwYAuIqiqiqDH84S7rD74D3loBKULHwSHEKCOII4IHAANsSySFD5JsgC6UeqWx/8IDDMzObmphSpyRn5iKaTEtBXd8/L/N6XN7xDVGZyviSjs0nLzH1cIH6F0t@M4shglHHA7KME/92/v8U@gmzSd@4mMSWRcbI4Zo9QthMJWQf4NSchfQFdAwn4lAC9kdRplaarElIyyZhajaAfOzo6EkiQwxdVKQFsrmc0tOP8wmQyiUAMVU2qyaT4qvQlB1UYVPIVX3UTiUsjmUzXsxXovlQYOrFwd0ODfik6vn37FkqF1nqUD6HHyMSyDz1bJE9w4JuAB4OZvx1Bz5Yk3l1mWp7fwR6jKxrjLC6xGNuKS3xVMEfCf2JRvViMoikO1FdjW/4qoLxG7IBDi5EaIuo/vAdXzMV9z70jtnf0@PH@k9NRo8Ekk@7ONJsj12njno01Twzj7T55yDcN6KU8ohGp1zHl07KO8kfaL6dJOh4@PD48KTNOE1FCsQBSvEKDx4IUJU2KjEbPtyNipYSMl7k48gm@y/P8x/RSBhOsVaRI28RuBzAc/rOK9NjrPXCm0FdPynJSy2MXLE5jrkz6ujNheMwY35MM1Q6Xkqvb20QkqXal0BA5GqFA81KtJpYYMU2qneyfQoTTI6bpaZVBz/0qW9CzuWxOz@TzuYKuZfOlbD5XzKS1dD6d03WtlM2WiqXCtVT7nE1VxE0B86A6MO3euL@JC3vks7Qcyv9mPZ3EPz2TgTdATGq5QmNjY3ClIIJnxAZXuELrGqxXCub4K/Aw6SsS@wo4wQNp4LIrJta8HR5VxMIjPP0jxlcfyVoOqm1cOgPG4eCkUfipjKC6QN899JMiG9/4xpjVatBpVg4PpAiInz7zF98oVkftq8Q3nYlrkm@PsY71mYVX@qgdyxsNjBnUxbQqRa6vr7sA6fCA6TWdrDxGB9/XbXJpgfl6akgRu1yuvtWyBSmrl8tvM7ougYP0/z/v@dDswvaoBmy5nRqB0QBjdjtlgLEFxtx2qgVGC4yl7ZQFxkkto6W3U5OaxKRtfoIWww26VXlsTvHAPu4m1zxz0FVxt0FVpgR0eVucSFkT8Wq4bcMxOlXcxYnL7WPxK6lT7Thtuk1M6qgtpzNTvfFsgMvyB45bjYKuFfU9LLygFfe2VeusoY6cEbSJeq6QqGtpkMz404pJPdlR2wPTcHdy5VwRLcGcyU4uXb607I5zqX7@@NEn4/Ho2KSV/zvZUrmj4jEZuKF9p1jO5Rr1uiwn6pRMAy8n5NVU2dgA1jaNjgLfrmOPPUUvNiByx3Kr1Wh0J6PpilbOpIvSdZB9CQiHeapJGDOBeUki8a5EPSjbjg11rpw0ktYV5bvc7Xavt64Sc4tkXCncBhS5Voxk6yqwVpRQuDKbJBVr7gkuRheamCsxYVSW9VxRrtQrc3shL1ca19L9odmxDFzvf5a@uh0rD7KJQ41AQmdMui67jjMut8yu45rzgBkt7wfkCN0OkJWvg@TO0pji1e3k8hgIaMgpB5zKzyur0Rq3OojTxj60ivXGtn@SGXKorit6RsloipbB/zsMOv6/f3gd/nV8Q6yMLp3ibt4nIFWh2bDZI9zbOHbYqePQHXkPzPaKEHt9gxbz7bmO5/0Dwjww7HPu9dDiR2gFXp8YeDmGN7TG/RUhno2GuFPSdP/RIOwPW4AgVWwK8ABe7sBxlgUosGdPV@TycXBoJRCDn1oJwY8PP/7kNPQ93d/d@0TKswdHTx7e@OREoBx7tH9wGlgL3NePmgtAfH3/0aObVvHJHj077k4cF3/SwdGz7PwVOOH@MCkLz2KgwJmAiBdaodGu0KDzBssVfIMm4Qrje9AXuyeMufzcmEbjc775zfKCFa98l2NZOvV3xBkMBVDLZG2@IRY7h3QWi1AdtUJJkkbMdi5ZIc06zmBg4J2j3Q1w7Bu408dE5WhAV@Ni0peOO@hcWh1zQ3qMm4pKGl6siEhInwCQ4aRNBx9YYwlP9urgbaA4ddEaTEw2wRt3VzjCB53Q6Fq9PjQwl44fQGoZBqNFLR/2QHwz/IzXO4x5GuR2y2dwO7gUkYyxESlW7t3TnrpQU2rpcrln7k@BS9kzqDWGO0sWc3JGbcsHTG1GWM@qe40RFFUmm9dQVQJdduMsnTKyznmZbaacETShryaJLLQ2Gxvjbrsiy9DO5cpA6VoxvZdm2Z3s3/z2j//@T38NBN1WCl4RTZZxWfOGJqmkL@ulYq5YyujFZLFUzOa0fC6X1PQkdEcKJdAg01pRyxdzJS1ZzJYywH0l8M2VClKErxlLbRFI@JYBrN3Ga/@2SeVW@zUpwieu2OuYEWcRI7BPmGxCHBkvevfGtG9yy6rKepZpaQa9LYBosDaLHBzspQ8OZPkBWnDCfi8tyx205IrpdOGBLJvks1dE5UF2eJwinp4ij7klnX6wJ8sTDgAPHpXlPlr28ziGI8sWWvZ2Dw4wnS5adIwPwc65D7cMfEsBgtloyWRoAYEsvwrAQbhdnlCWMN1HC6aJPgfcZw/8ZPljH590GiAc83Acwid@Xnd3ZfmQW3Z30WePMp7jqH6Kll16ZNkFC1QFWe6BoedCJZTlFhixQshyG0ztmQFueMkink5pjw1ZnnECIYlkeUqhjfa5LDd9d0zmk08@Mfrjjtnjz8zl3zagBj7WdLJ/0Pr441av13Jnu/sfH6PP3t4nRnc2cVu9lojWasLjQBzwOR/Obj6A42GzaQyW@nwKPvYNn@asaSJuTeMV4CSeHiYybO6Bzx74LJvz49DgGULQFj4PhvB9YLTIx3/Ih77TVkuuIKOi/ko3JUOdoUuLk0Oj7ToVtE@rG4xFY9HkrJ5PNyrkwYagqaYr13RFcgzfBo4OxK9m9Wk13ahOqwWdLxbpxuSzqZ6z5OTGcEcr5cobxo6mZxPTMu6edrpRFlW0HRbT7m29ZrEn8R09ky3LZzs7ilzXGju6ViznC19sTWQ5Xsb3TqZQhoDpKPSd8RWvFxo7hVwoSqGQMFJ6uVCIV66BHGNohFvYa2/GYpemcR6PI7rY54Ms8AuaZ5RPq9KNTZPTKseLzeKVaVWr8IPTWPoWrA6e0jlpjx2XQ@wBuOlOukxXQMtaqShD@qlULB4HyURCBL7zdWbPv3Z6fnr6Ocgs6E2LvuhTfq9oRVg//mRPhe6psOHpmuoB9hMcV91DwbLgww9/9J1OQZlWP4FWD7oSvhvuaHGdgbo/bZsj7Gz4Hv6Zaao46Uo9/WQBzgl0xHnKuCG4QudJ2G2T4eGjVocZ1RqYjA6LEVbMiF9Se9us1arN6pDf4lwLYn3K6GTOOZhDj@MebFOm6Fe4y0N4NKvp60qrOo1MAU6zyhTtxdDpvNAT7UoHzxx9UH2AkStN@LYqZtXEu6zliFzp7thVxia2Z3TNp6aLm@4Pjzah9cetH7EuM@Ob7Ixuvt5DlftaqbnMnmP2ZDKMGUqtFV90ClmRNLGv@Vm@or1IOIt@XelWWeyLeOUVWN1NFuuoD@I72Uon9oA14@CSftF90WU6y2crdBlgDCFBJSLa0I3S8WrtU1BYOODzchkQEWV8DjAxJQBrdcjDiI@s60q7OmAxhU1ZnMiTrfSqdYz9Bl/biiw3FKX@piHVFOW5VIN6WplFjKo3adFB1Szd0vR0vjIFN62QrfShYI0vphW3Opq4ZmUAVjEww7dcGRUgJ1ANwLx@E3v3i9@Mbyu5KnerEKg3A9ARmmqzOq3YePQNsEQ1UwWPRD2bTkJXFF6FJDTIej6p5ZOZZDapFNAVWuNkLgmO0B2Blj82iMmMycn0NK1qSc3UkrH0C6vzIp48j4GOQSRj8eTY2ceLtMEFCgm5kqzwNVg8oW8NGJSCw4xthdgUJEUFMwY077ORlewjqGPTGFCMeFxhma3YYDOGYTZPJ6P9eqNc3p@OvgZeMeXVTj5RSCdex@OV2Ea8CmqKVKtINZQqlOvRBvCsGLNi3mRYhzIeb2oFvVyvtzCHhXQyk85A5qzmm962XJMbyfRGXoMSumakxzAuMLguM9dG5m5NVJLxVnqmlfSKpNJyC0pRi@klfcW4ZFzChX4CoDQSwg7py2Jnsr/pMBaNFvRoNB6t4Lj1hiwGIUHC8QvuQdRG72k7MuhPclku6RhgLihpX1k6rEJdS9ixZ9mSFLmSrq@ut6FnmqJ1d6gHbpBJUWv3pUiZMdDjzsTJJakNxj50OV9iu/YF/57hamKAK9HRdaA50hob08LuFPsM99DusCggZrjDuq5nGnW9AO0byEw/qK5rFRyrj@CyZbUGlPeuAL/tRA23n3zKZjMjofiUvcdYL7EpUaYjN8m@W93tHe9WfNseDh@eSbIsV6Jy5CoaiV7DnxS5T3tedL7nhUVCu15wPBqHcoE@byMkMdjelT9qVMYLVGJGmcuHeiP@9ok1uCpmFD40AALr@jqymaISEVsHKp@@0HNQRrbj7yWA7gwOwUDTlcvh2Gck9WLkfUMvZh4fHtkP3QNT7CQoZptyLcLSmoIr8ytl4Zrjq4TlUlGX9fNkhN2PVCLsXIlqZdptMDopfVH4ovjF42dHz44OpMjZxpsNB4fBmU8V9tb@6tegGxDNZKOMnVUj02q2IhZV1WqKtq3jkUAFVgZZ39XySvpNjXNvjTzyOvi8@8XfzE63i2DXQXktQwnmEnqtpm3pLB4ZvfvyD/AsiKv9z3YfsahnzNjf/@mP9MLf/@m/osVK0euKR2OwhQiERKOWL0SurkZXV9fwcL9cpBHhSGULcTDz8X0tUktpesa27Qorpwxjq5DI6vftSkqE1QpaPOIpETGLUchFvDfCS08XwcufZiAnOY8lENk/tnK6dn8beUIL9kGx4G/b9ErAFMXHL94wBpZ2rdPrWTqZUilWfquw7bfKNnuLw/ZvlQ32olrDmWENd0/5A9VbuEkEZ3@itURqK8r0HPjVryuNBKOhbujafWGaW/bZDY4@28A16ItOWzb8mVse/WEk38EDq28zt156cmwrnkp1OuLkoG2T5WrAClspwOws/u4Xf0PX83//p7/6pvmm@bkOfbhSKa/pkZ9pP/sZBFizg9/vgNGIPm61R0PQcWMr7taGDqkUwQvXu4yH97tx2HFD7cHq2dARR5t0gRoPlVKTHwvViVGwLdzgmyT9mQ5tiVckKdAzST92e@0kwWBbeO8B1FLpSvoKekGzyqogOKWvzEGBwxAaUqfd9AYTd0TbAmIUT2sk2T2IAil8BU/c2qCNyUL6KiCwUlu3o3KUPaIaaUdsaHoent8F7Yn0FYgizqjD65wN3EOPIS0bxL2KQQhP8ujUIe0GpD3gEZrkGqPc8wBJxrHjkWzQoaWvgFpAVLBAW2DWNgSogIj5ChAA8hATgK0G22aZOLuyEonK/HCwa1wFjQeZGf7@XQmjIbQO7hf3I1cwHDiB7o63IiFfiBIGRS3k6APhMPh8bRW0f4xONlS/aIP9e4MCWHSYTYyyxu7dm2NVrVqdOKMcIfxza4TDTVQO9nJcAZjfc/qoU5aTDI9dq/iuAdsBxROELnCdws9bq4SiMhmt15IE/@/NtMiRN4qKPCqYAVFevFa0gWQQGcnOy7DNtqtM0wtxFiDfBtzbhBQd9RV0B8@mH6n6577nNWD4s4h/5jgIotPwEJ7g25sbuBk0gBM88BmP8eHCQGy85gf1oEA7HPuxg1iQFWtAobuWC10VmkX2T/2KZbQ4RpufkkZ40LpmPctweXEujh@KhaEZfA0830qks0FndLQdKFBv5Nh0IBYd3oFrt4EjQEaJc4U42hP7Ei8IEGVDkcMYeXSmEHI@YkwHfNHNihQXp2lbLvRnfdokmdlTWXvYYXqJxYjR6PwjOwAXp0iEcAv0XqRxa2AOAaUT06SdNV45leqBfjRp0SFQjy3gq/6BBa2K7aXEJZapS@vcSp3iAceK08UNOHxLfQRVKqx@fEZYHLg0cJxzNrDOTT4yG1s4kMBjoPmD@poEys5/QNgyrkbQM0mWBu8kDwW/AnwK3FhMhuJuxGbx29@MthFrYom@oUbGcvGCygvDDtGXnjeS6Ox6M88/0oQO5gC7GohcUxxmUI3iNuXglA5JHM5SpXNBVBzxH8Wg6@kfaoJG0MrNC4bdVgnbGBCabf94AKzFkNuvUANAdQ9qFp5vNnbLeKgFYOJ2Ym2oekLA2@wjltElDMhPnBGnwwAMLPrqInTwg6iYD2/cgYJR@YYzkCtQO4cd8MPt1IL9ML7P3Wims@fm7M02BDhsdCitKuPVwrfkQhasHcjPlPUN8MwDhksw2YjJCQCbkOMyBx3Evxmdc7tEsqTMbkNKMoQgSA1QSFXwb7BloZP8JfB4YHj8PExxEtrl5aVKR/JNXEs1PTzd3sNreVOjngXasZMam8ORuEfMwvsjBdy5SeGXWuBlzTtTuia5dG/Gv5LU9apivUYs2vWi2Dhe4OHtvSEd5YNn6HjEUAcWXfzQjoklJpz/9Ebyyue/MvKfUoxeIxDGEMw0OUu2kwAs2WqfJ7uXnYrwuKAKCcChFE3fEY/BdH3L0PNN1qgbhHDGtE/Ct7cG5zR7CZBkPog6T5rn0A85863CPrKmEMk2L9mu6xqzGPnHMTQycGxGag@bQbNPPmCEZoZd8TMZrWl91liIPg2iQ6Pmd36Yi@f0SFfrgfIDOtF/yv2n4D/l/tN5on6y9WmDq2TodI3ZQa7H4938kAhm5oe55odZzn0IMujYTOMgMORswe0afu0qxfbpzW1QjlWfMYAnRkBwM5aqf3FWP2vYnnm51UikesDsMhECShxA1xtE08tOYEbqDy4GI8dbcLLxVD9olQTe6NTuC27gvIJ5DAqIGIPTy8KD2HpDMevPFQKRYYCAehh4omqwO45Z8UpwICx5AuPU5TmNOWJ1gUyDtC/hJdxAXeKk54QNA2qEAKF7kCVAE3yYX3P4XSa@dHju4pXtfliFrl8Y4oFA0UYUKHmjqnBZU6FCCmGlKD6aQHZUV6s3s@L7Q1HUb3iFsnktyj@M/sYHo9@FerEce2JY3mBUpHBVwQVsoEKI6kJUZbVqqFwBg9SWMTBdaLn2uX4qWmtIZivldzN4OpgF7xIvaI2FCr8d5@VDe9dkWy4HrDCrViGLsyqvlrxe@CTlBA@ieSLazGcEEZ8LEICRXhrNFNGm4WjTapULDjZdEe0yhOSUkJzyKDz0dAWSDRENek/Bzd5YPA3QTnH5nAzwNN6Mgho0khne0oqT0C/xsDKcrxRpzmUOcYHgIVSxkc/ajaWp10NIh4TWDQDIiLcAdPi1aGXppsDTlMAWyChOSl9GcZtgAy4rgMFIBFf4gZ6xgMmoDwwKv5ygdgDqrpyoS7JGI7z4l@Y/Oek7@j/ttmN6MaS26JhO3vj7R3FsIGVDFTSkfWjpLApk7Mk8E/fZL@gcEbxBtO@AVte6dFhsibIN7qmJiJpqDZxWamjgYhK8LElcIDyaxf3@A86OsPsjZ2yMnWy2zDtNFrHdsvR5n8Hq2Q6esR46yBd0vY5jenZ0DIXadnq25ZlJhuetnZui22GKc8OlsJ4sjI4nSWI0kndjETTnK1R1m028vrHZjOFSuHg5WGlLK@OQPaNRCfu/YArFB/EkgB6NYk7rpdkex@@GiWdOi2inVvs8djQSnlFIZJeBDGuD/g@@fdBgmOfMe450@i2q0q1xjC5f6DtDpwda38RTJYx9A/zhHDYiZIxGhEuSGdilLYdOHqdaEmsnjbiI@ukHR2Wf6jEjHsTXFwEsECPJ3Js0Rsq6S5JrrkyOR/PTO/lwfE/C@J6sx5d64Tdx5l3zKvf8sKQzsTkECDhHI3M3Gph1kFudW@gsoBI4o17FI7w3ih1arNVBTHch6K4IrnaBP5KBzQNbgPhnq@i/vgD96PvvW3wG3ml7MgN5M8Q1hDG6N8DzpzljEPwwHpciS5ILWPvhe6YFYfFGogNUIUCNJcFl48GdUDFH0O32guPkfcB38Dyuj7rF97Roqso9l@DkXiTZub66iB42O@bAmJmdmAiZDMH1c3wMHTaSV@@XcRR0JPQc3teLQdsVD3yhGUei80DlFSxjJC/i8dVsxYNYAffQSDlheLiafuh/SzTjEF@Vj1ZDPyAajeBw7IWFw5@j2WjGz4Ye8NtMhBzl7Q8vSdyffzdBgA7iAJzkPNn4OvF5HAuy9B4tQhBWXcwyHt3qQ8TzY26X4YeR6O6cQuGGIlX9UpYW7zlYXuLWuhIPcYXPk3wK6f1Y8i6me2@eC7EaBzYXYXsf1oTcgowrM9rtWBgid1lbYo59SyagG43T2StaleYSgRrEJEk3tqi7TfpFXMKe8SF8ccDpM/giwJ45bnKG8vOGY1riHhZGPkNjFNJahAso6QAlREVOcoFGKJTkmyH41XWQZntlmu1babYX0gxqwGKSoUBSeyFJUQpYPOuKYGB2xyukM3ph3xk@68Q2PLZjuDhacRW1omUryaIX0TII5KgZLe/HQChHO9HyQzJ40fIJGc6j5U/BMK9b0TfRsl8tMIALVjLcR3chwtHejpb3YvFraWycm56frhotB2UKYXa4lSgCpMB8g9aIU2y2I7I5dk1o2EipTDLkGC@J3Scah0nSLw3//OYSugEBPXGMc4sCswTTFhqNUIvB04Fmwz9he0lNLovWfP/ogFY2BUEwmQT08cJxCDyo4ZHoojDiiKEvzWjAFxBEuVlejhELtWTviY5IHTiUCnkxfaKeSvpAJ0b@dQjcmCdC19WI@H55LYLgBfh@eGLkVXjeQsdPjjDCOdn4ErSQqC@iazKFZb2Iiyj9cAnRWPdiILwU2g/CS4nAhmQ66HA0OYeJjZzRIpOQLy55t8JxaFCOV0rk3hvRSCqImrnCm5xFzlAwhCt/fF12QvEQtQURhJ71dIPXsqBdIFmMXnNZF9JUeeUDFEIyB2q42T6nq4AeCiOF4@ImSW3FqmbIj8uTJMm1KCYhsooHDU2MMU896Lzu4/FDH9Z99WNOcawlhgBCMYNUuHx1PkB/d7j@7ivUPhFuJLBMsV7elN5Wr9e2sjcwH8yTvV2A6JlkD@NLlaMghTnJoXcQ0szX8dotFR@XfHAlnycaQL@h7ftkC/oEd9DtZt@Cw0Itwb1YdDzXwfFcX02o2xrJ4EL1lRYVUxJweMYDTOdZW48rz/iyIkYfGt82Bh9cwO5iAYcLD@FRBtwbJOe13J3YtMplXrdBbHMXFKlamXFBTtOlQTHPHUHc09RtMG0LDkfN44dHTx59HRrdQqEQF230bI4f1locaw3acQ6ZlkkH7cGSbouexNs9cLIbh@PpAvaNM1u@JUu4sAZlwIBUfPYTdTwuZFlInt@ouxCPhw1RVMA6n1cDY0EqoapjYJNtCbqOgSDmOLZlCCC@egv0TlJvLU73WDSbeOl2s0nNV7OJi5eaTdGKYdH4M@Lxn0U2UhPPpYsI@SUsl5JEZwiwh0fs@Se7p@z0k3128GzvU/b1o2fs@e6TU9wb/vTZg0eHewx@@09O9pm0sFASL6zCDiXQ9aHZNvFeQTylLcsI8p4zmnG5E9uLc/cTY8g@cdomTlNte8bwfp9bVNsc13isfeiOznAM06JLyYbWGNdb0I1a0I1F5aZD2/RwVT@DsC3o0w6xzzt0OlbXgrAS9n1Hlun5O7vYwIISBHnrb9NNciUJL8@ipUN0zR2uwLqE6AaEx7kbAGPw9Vd0r7nl8QhmR2WCcMHzwRQ83T9@fMLwtIG9oycPD08Pj56csIOjY7A@/frhk4@Bnocnp8eHD56hFwV8fPTw8OBwb5ccOAJpleH@/5cTb7wWBRWDE1Xa5zjzTdfXB7bFUW/U4NmlQRsWPRad2Ch9LGNgvTY70Yo08VB9wU2SNFXAYpu7xx9/Bm0@M1/hDKc/FUzrD@RnHl3itplm25QaVJYa1LeKqK7Q7ClanOYjhjOGdzqYFdrqHyNzkvnAaRFPxzKZvIdrVHDsm58IQHXZBw0JbQBsBOUvWKkyuoslGk1uE8gapNYeOHhGI0@NLyIUFox6319qUpGIYmKtDALFnQuHNo4HaZXAAfgeHHSR7NjlAVgmcOABWJY7oCp6iGtHWE6EmIyPJiieWZ47vByODmhamBUChwcG9WKLAideblSkBgvussLzEQZ04w4f5aGbAA2vbVkUxaPweBvNYMArhsnvQQOZyKcSaW0bhJRB2HRxqkEse@MXhqIvcAOuEzK6Y4/FqnGVneLiINO2@F1HvYFh8yVQ86U7xHusiEfbVMWp4lZwRxDtBRk5xIB4P9kiHkG8h0IrNN83HsR8cCtFQ6yRpHv6/CVodyHw4BYCPw8YAKQs9HTa1FLRHlIE43QFK8c8BzgSx23fhsMDO3cmbXMhgli1FXtpvX4dF0ROLvST/HWKhB0U0WvTBbWSpjK7jgt1nMQq3aqCUrDdd0Zji5dhbDEHNONEzRyExoYNUntRrS2khnS4maLt2KFEW8DFK1JtAVO@T6rE8XzuPBBf8ys2gfOhEebr7hAdo4XXt8/nzpI4iXRp4vALKMI0V46Dn7MxYcL1T2kuO94yvKWvWK09fHCmvH2RxKv6uFjgt2P6iw7xB4yJaUH1oHk@WrDoot4lapp/xZI3aWFssQZPSEus5T4w6Af2LejX3W9WAj@@3Pi2O@6WuelOjm/e/D/FPe1WGzuSv@mnEG0SuqHdtkkgBGMSAybxLIEMhuTmGOJr7Lbpucb2dRuwb8Kc2f2xL7D7fx9hX2XeYX7tU8zWh6RWtw3J3ew5N@cEd7ekUqlUKkmlqlKJS2VRMskLU6MrJ5ZunqirKj0qcyGkCYghOwFZkPWO@uIRTC2vX6OHDPZCESjSRzmC@/bUBUZShKjWXd50QLLIeyRld2v4rtghi4r4Wl30cTH7I/fZ2S2t7ri52KBEGOR0lIj2FOSC6xpmKTRfzYDbfxwcyO/vB7f5KHY8PfwuaPuPQvtduGVXH4bF05IB6/vB/vURsDy5/Z/AQtu9hwHzJDkLTXO6Zk5vKaOtaR@v8eeZvqOxB2Bw7kUNigZq1HbTpyNqFRHZ4QKuCSZeENVO9ysnJ8Lm/QmUBbmHW4a2FIMIe1G8j61twz4JO18vmvRmWS@e1JeERZv699hgnku8B0SFXIN4kh5aWMQXSHfCCUs9ObPQEoKs70kgKsolsfuiZFBUl4DvYQ8IyMadZjTQmtvMDE8@YWQagUu6ebw2Nm34ycKa5268nXE0NQGZNkHNLnqWzO@/j7w@3lL18AILA/Fgg9uwkob5BvYJNah4CBl9P9mDj3SL6lI0sucFdkbRDg2/8skV9o8zFDESL8J5LWyIdbk4lqjx@nhJLXPIIBGngSZaespEtmiGBCXi6cu22aFuPOk5ySkIFpl4X99rkyug@MV9Ud8g78TzZEkvyM2xtkTY1BWWF6idlbCLD2d6grbQG2nxkK4KpO2jVWX/f6riWSJRk6L53MaoRIC8sb7@7Fuw061QxbM/CpvnkLT8HF8PYX8fg4ymEan3gXOrR55KjxngEdKxab0aMKmCsNSZM6ck2k6TkYkf4MJ6IUAGI5HjFYjpWl0xSeE2HzrPSCZ0yjLTBmMI64byqJmh/v3j1aFA/mZ9i7@/Ph5smAlNB@/RKv/dYBQFsVeeEU/F@ISerMlvwWjUp2zsz3SNUBxyY3rU2Y687djglVuFiXTeZrakI72T2OzWU7oGqoTUiz7eeoravWJavZctFM2mHlQPK2KFIgp2ErpIe2S7huxZDPuPIUAymPQSOH2QD9@TaAv@Aw6eAglkIm8@h2jjfhM3ogismut0P4w0C5WytZDu/U7UavYxuIdnP4mE7T2FgqSFrRwfuPM06/liojwgFw37DpTy7KxvU1H4hgpdhJQEwb2J340JCz01lKXkI3fVN3OFzfzGS4ta1/fG3nX95YW30irZAibfZv86uhndtX/pDq5uO6Inhn@5nLSmv/0qxPpz8Qyvr3vKYWILG6Uchd58AX83xcs8ca5E8BWFvD23hfD5fjwhlkW8Dy8uCr4bjjbNW@ghkeJSsXKtuBBd7Mal6/rGRalfyhev6/2LIjr5jVdL49XCqoMfnsIsCjKGT@br4wucU02ta9C/FXhtKl1vJ11DBLmGwJd3zVE4OCwfvUlo43ABgCowaetNCnW@8XQBrdnQ98TvB3eOVJN5AjnWwgWStUBeQQX0bid9Mqpj2iFgBr3iwWo2mtDfqWst5P2b4XhAKSpEILKW@Bp@tRaUG1OeNAqQpR6qQIJ00Xs0ifM4eDDEX6dsRZ0t8HKtgL6TrgGijiVJHNrnto0@hYio9OWqX1iRHzRbV4gEXvH7lYqJ7W268BdYLfJJi4emHM0ROUzkL/ARD0DgZ0inDVgFrdwjcvuwoPn4XsAH/kI6qjH5yZCBvEUrRUxB82/xhfybqPw2EIAJv8BrLl@qOOXKCxaS7DtIygUMNJbc@OMxA7pVcqcsYGMRNtdXioGTpTjRCKuVZILvC3dITqYV/JMtyBbobaYZOr/L2YkkdE4t3yKkJXUpJe3gTy8u5hjFsqqYymyQYuGb1EBNF2yP3gUwrKZiL@j1AGmmxUJMDnwk/15Z/6quP6pjnRcaeU7PzqRnE@k@pzNScS4fJvg405aZyc58ifPdCzvO5s3UVRK0ePGhp1s@LEnivMXH8kb@eNAI48w7uiuZK3XCdiIha6R8ntP7nLKYKKMZXKfXOV3y95rseY1lIu/rZP34a8kOCsh4VtqapLjU74e9V5a8HVamIJvZQE0huDj2N7EdD0rpgynFCazgUM9Pw3anFENZLSiJQ2PG3tl@bftykfHKSaPBXowzA2vOGDGoRHWuEuEm5LAI9VDyogGCYCKjCTVyd1ThqSw8NcBirkVVLXtBzgxwaFp6iJfQL/Ir/lGDPYmcypeZn7jAmE@48ezdnCQQCd1Fez6ZktIE3UX4o2zUI7NIXPc0DXG@kDgytMC6zoB9sDuoBl/UcsIUFEpSzNBdp0hKxxkKin0f6kJMvLf@mVux3jRhjT3sBRNRxm1Gk7ywrISD@ziIxhFGeaKoNNHNcNjDU0da8N2RC7WMGbK2jsctMURjZvetKlr2cH4Pn6RDOhTyxTFCvkMDkTghuul20ZkMPWAHdyhaUeMSjn2r3J@yQgPGzLM1djMPxE3Ep6aw2@@aSHDP8ehBSkfDZivwLVijRbD6sbipnVDezkj6dPQbwThiMKVtWdafb8LWL3tv8Dz3RSH/rGCQ7FYeB@f9Z89jBysgkkpYy8Mydr3w3LKMs@EWnw1nEaAnDnGi/wC8GdwG/X5glWHGoIwRLFqjYHQbtH3LOgn0ITDCRVbGk0n0wx7cjFqs3IFFVxOYEb2EI4@Pw4DD8BfnZz4ubtFZmWfhoVV82gxdfRu2kYDK46QzwNNhOrDAMAFMDyx0HYyBKCuuSKJEZ88SF1q7XKMiCqiBcU6MswlNhv5gHLagZ0iTZfUAFB@DxJX12ylMoL5Wr4nOwf48BNA9JqaAQkAdJT2GgyUPzX8XDkI2TJ2xN1XP5ED6DWiswHAPRiFI35jA1CtUzMAdOvj0bbUmascHpx/LJxUBz@9Pjj9U9yv7YvcTnXHjQTlFwRVvjw9BuujTdD41P4YPdrkGJW1KsMpHn0Tlp/cnlVpNHJ@I6rv3h1WABuBPyken1UrNE9WjvcOzfTp9Bwji6PhUHFbfVU8h2@mxR7WqYlZcThwfiHeVk7238FrerR5WTz9RjQfV0yOsDE/1y@J9@eS0und2WD4R789O3h/XKgIbZu1Xa3uH5eq7yr4P9UOdovKhcnQqam/Lh4ephh5/PKqcCDISMFq5WwEsy7uwhcWaqJ371ZPK3ik2KH7aA@IBgoeeqL2v7FXxofJTBZpTPvnkSaC1yp/PIBMkiv3yu/IbaJzlfIMq0C97ZycVDIWElKid7dZOq6dnpxXx5vh4n2hdq5x8qO5VakVhHR7XiGBntYon8AY7qhpgALUgHZ53z2pVolv16BTmjLP3aO/gQid/BMIAlmUouk8ERjMIbC0Q6fjkE0JFOlAHeOLj2wp8P0GaErXKSAW0qNg7NbNBhUDEU7OZ4qjy5rD6pnK0V8HkYwTzsVqruNBh1RpmqKJBxidgHaj0jFqN/QR48SMwq6U416PuFNUDUd7/UEXMZW7ggFpVcguRbe@tpLmPcXENJUo4QJ1B89pUrHRmP90GGGZyViMzX0ejIybtHe9XYEaWcavsOOEMZp3NVCglMw1mGp0Ir4mQNe3g8qbbCPudAfqY6mKs@LiOuh7eCePijRnn1iM3ckj9ChXIZBqND@UGbHRrjYbrfU/JBBrfKiHV4I/lcmUbMfw/7rxR8bO1xXTfThBq56k86CRDPTyAwJxM/ads@ta8DlyRy7UDWQyd9xGwUh1FfGxyhUcpIBrJ2RGv@YirJM0EvYeSHaigo8D7rQbqSdEykjINIvjT/xq/8ORgfADpzOquXA43sYRG@FugquFKKCQC/ZERCcIOVelHQfBL18mb1eGe3@8OBm3HdVUZyjuGfWDXcb9R/DLopopn0@UJWTp2llH3I7XvpiWMPn@WJBOyX/wRtczBP40x/bgKG475gFpTqoqU1VJp6Tzl4miR5AkZ2gLdK6iTcc33rvxT9SPu5vJrz4up72/1dx5baC@I4WhhwqtTuQv6eXvBGWCAUSwOIEkoI2TkckYZZW@iM99BxivMdBe20fIH5uqrgOZ1IAksZG@aPbNOnI1H4cTEHuTwm5Pyu92zgwMQnYjt8831FxtFS4fd@snj309YD8WMpahjQ5jHYZ1GScYo2YOFD40UI6p2zP7EwLkcZsTo6arT6CPGedB2G0lLJhRk2NwI77zpo4meHSAdbEEBOBYtxa9zR6ZkACfRVBdbc92c0BK/CWsl4gFpzNKbUq9N8A/C1sNfDXHdIMlAksUoii5wLuwuSO7ZB8pUlDY3FLgHs/i24mMO46ZpQKousp9F71p6k7xt9GLEpow4XqnbqSQgsZjGQii7ij6P7PcUZ0QqgCl6GHz5SfIbPH6SAe4o3F0zGpfHNSDjgS6JeupYGS0bXZeQL3ZK0EVPn@qatgVq@V2JFI09qU7WgUGM0UCo4I0laOObBFzUcUTSVZIF7OtlV3xhTsXgHQinKDlWvgPnzmuOhFJU8UPku4pKIRiWDnLCVLvTdVgqyycdx0KRM0GmH6IHwf8DaTIH/jbsOAF6TC0jCOB3UZKgMq1g@0pECe/UQYNxuhFT0/z0KQZzb3bMlW6YPL2ZsH8NkED2zlR9@ERhDzvOHAIgk6Niwxy/2iTtqglbp9e2K4vjOUm/dT10hJwr1FQxAze7ceHRsstTZyv44gqXdU1GhYdQVLzmjdsljXrYMqW28uJJZDM4V8X/yK2QAkQPeOLSK7ZaTXNWXo4yJQdkqCVjwmnriEmwLL1/8NRuRRghMhOyX558KUIB6B3EZ7addK3HQLB5bjLiIs3E4pSi4GFkcNwm4@QjQ9ZdkiFmL0A4T9qkDMGbP8Z3OEH0GDqF6ouhCecJGYpgJbHVYRxnEMWt6wNpaVq909iTZhI5VGN/1ueQ9AFrtVQOnwN8SAxNd3lfvGtOAeXe9zWbWSy3Uht4aLuIlbFaQpbHW05ag8EIlo5NbDfg6IVT1xcfpdIh6Ec3Ixm/EOazcCQ1EmrRD9Xgsol37zTNcDR4Qi0Kx@it0PaJP6hJ1wFaiHJ4kkl2QzjAvIpHd5TSMZysFoSzHadsA00oLCkRcVtsiK9fORcTVIYMDYiCYaQ3F2SzSfXguYMefneD0S849@MSqN8O2joyqQGSdIHcSdU@xXhsjbnpw0FEGg3oCtSAaEoUWJGmDVVhjn4h2UnaNdlxdEyMXUot@f31aCZV1lJQUcy4snZgvo0sdCZSaU2GBtXBQgtr64TKvA3X/YObMYoWmjy2FvZ5X4uULV5ElJ6opSM@sdzUT5/wSSr5S08iHD3wBc@45RIUEcY1K56rzso5wg9tCj6Gwaht6kRhJdNuDlH9RlufQZ94UakOZdi/VnMcBVPYAbRy4SRHMBrOnwZX/cbeoNfshoOwCfs0DOg@YYmHj1N6xA7rjgZ3EV3gQwltI1N7Gj9zfBkOw4bv@lyyaITmisbB0DHNFMajafmKw0SQ5hyNAOO7Kom/h@kYabrM8/W4kJX0PyV7vIJbfLDss8K8wnyijwCkgNtJWVCwD@mYHJMM59PiTIbLxzIYOF6KrGi6D1jsJTB@CSSiY5gExgqZGbMEsxG4M3sQ43p74rUpBuEIAy0F@wFePhM59Nlr4vW/IEVeoaXAlihs5o2ifIoywTiE@DB9mNxrL/5g7AGBH0C/8Gwet8xjBBJxHRVtKeL9iowyCriQeWBIMpokMUixsAuzUC8BtDFJQ00mTx@iBln@wKJIhtmb4UockQ5sfPCeOacBIqcxdXFSWRbLLsXtwCVIeezkH2bY4Fv2szT48RCXNWcomPYkZMdA@iFStYBKeCFqyrzWRJljKn97xKytfW@vpQhYmmdyZlz069hq5UIeKCHPr3isNRiBMLZT1JOmHsvReDBc/k7qPSg75kZmm0frlut@0xCYma0Ek@VKm0hbmuLjtGil8UkxTZJiZGkGPITbV3rWbJ4m4qTUwPFWaky/QYeHaBbbTelJRfd3m8c@Toq3aNGrJho9pAh3DFJa1N/rDWh442EJImHy9qpBEqOBIqMx5UcDVIpMmkrfTyHiPol7ih5toBzW2wbamf3zIFHTRnIq5KlKSgS5RHpi4HZ02gS5NOyg8QWGieMVrhZSesE58aZ0lFfIXmKQYUxggLgqDrKxHoo1uHFnpfiIbgfoOA20FiqgJIKnHdPCQQf91wSjqPxSuSMtHhrTbOGiyJAmGhLsKijXY5CUvzm81hsTgjJDChjic0ihWzQjm66@v1U/2hbIBxC4NCVLS9@8h41xxSpgA3/MpMYE18BxVbJkYkQlB0KDRAOMBdildHsBb1dx9ReOmOPRukEOI9hA8GcHf1ZlCQznvZHX1MYik/YUs7iS3DzaXJHd4SIxQ/E7kl8ORV7q0sYVAASMMZQvFQAChjUl7PFQgELvmJyXQFT2ERQsFXBYwkeKihrbec5JR6LKDM/XjRz5eTlemjCyc4HAwmJ@nhgRWLPMzxJDgYluLi5Gjhfz2xPngAWx4n2mOHSF7JUkDXXPMQHpBuS8G0uUekF4ecnBlPh83U0kav6m1Jd5IzWfTgX6aAzr2UI6dTOfSE1Uu7aWLJooCfRwzVoTiUAK10RYS4Uf@0euKWbIc20TamwyEqsMaZ@NN1TDLhP2bf5fIrFNTtlqjaHgmZ7havvV4CtWEkHZHw/ALpbpyABjt/9wa5VlqsJE3hVAcemUs4vDG0Jasdo41WOzcKerIu3pAAVqTzvoiA@nBweJsK@XU2VodB2M1vP5PDLxpRn8XtlWoyopHOSSuXOdm14vN7z70@jDZY5kfxDQlQBbagcdQJfAoIj8wajLN0MgDpAVc2elIyvu9W86HfMKBjyhxM6DbuOcMhqCoAko1EYvH05JAUQg5QT7MzYQ2/ez0KPvrskLTQlFHUNBaTQJvrXV6RmQBz900D5bn1QRMBTMypoJ5i23tPMFZxC82YQ6i8IXu19i82T7bdDrDTzxEa8AxkgBC/fpAgcHZoE8Z8ETRvLuvYkoHq0ngtuwZ/gVYxaT1xGcmpjUPRMqLjzGxj8JupXJ0LHrn22YVqDJq9jMVYxP7Qm7a7syWPx3gGU@BLS/K/d1c@i0iE7pzDDVyxEcPwFGzwre3L1PIotLOjFJs2/nRqLOR9enYA3QdJfWAiqWPXUvteSB7Jq49vmk0EEa5hmGxAljrnxfCXQ1@@PE4u240/k@qUjXAHDH/i6JyDeh/JhApDMAGoFy@AE9MYr2v2RhWB@kAorwAgcv65iVO1iggQUs60mr9OudUy6XxdJwdVWUy7vwkM2K8m5Z7OOH3V2xD@@7@P60tLa@XmSZu@9@gY@76uO92AUYpOFcbV2N9uEV0kroN4bW2tjFS7nSkldcapS2d4pRrl7eRbd@ePrHv/77P/7tP3Jl@fJf@LJLL/XPOpPv@7ml1pelp/dFfK/vXywvXdaXhhfL3SJy2T8pavigOs42Y/NRf3RpZXgWML6SHanaZ1P0GVlUqPv9rpujX0C6bIlMK8pl5NeIb44iGZtpBcb3AP0oL2ELry4dSG/lAYkMAJ2iOh56pxWgAR7MN0BJwAXtQLk8n60oxT2Gg9EZ9KlKRkbioTXrbYA@LXEkBfTFhRkrG/ajoI8a8Fta83LzLKsJv@G4Ifk39/ld1N0dTMTKuSNW8mLFEyu2TT@FjZfw1V3Kheidy9lgO2DbHqTERwtoZiiikBZ6tH@gu3ZS5LasJbqyByGpMBWUmb3gPL37I2cZvnAt6loLeH2mYBUJHTJhkcyXpf49dMsXyHFvJ1xtaKHQkLsYqsw4UdH9i0ugZsSGAHHN10yQrQFUiSd95JGMTzn1Rfa1RbcJEWAk68mbAxr3@AHmoqW@tHlO7KXwmiMyn@evODcW2Rma0MYUrj9GgA5UeDuZJ0/C5cyyxVbeRiupmeyFbbZPMh/bOkyDsbJN50J/FQYTsDW3SbilvvRrkYbcfLwi7FAfrxhV2Wnbb2EZRa5veuNwKN0VqHYcUF90bfc8krBHCRDD4Zj9W7MjjBQFKlJUqlv4sqypaA@w6TwS@tI1HTrY9fnkyCBC7rMDY/tramy7OfISUezAPEBIaVO@TjPsRTLqyoiI3W2OLvF2wGaHLlQb87kZ6fPwwtQUxoOORtonyGRyHo9naEpmOGp2r5ueyBwNTkfNaRWmLVj5jFu@Cy3EEEyIBA4@WfW85imEuUWyS4giuilkOYSXF/Sm8no07ltb@5xgl6qhIMOu4CBIsBNRMvia6KsUHWOu/h2dYKI8I7z1aaQUsSR50dJIQrJNtxkaZjNDx1I1mGNHDxzbYlT1yFS8IAvd4ER7TQe/IMl7GCNA1m1LL0DpirDxEuvH2akb9JuJyWnYs5Sjf64oeF7E8UxXUbI1kqUuQS3EN94hVrCO/JyMAsFzkwpnZC04zsJ5JK9zy5jzCAX51rb4uaYI9QV0dIEZeYaIs37IwjI1Q8V3YPiiSpb/AKHTa3YBv@ldc4qseJ5xXi3m3Prn8/7FinPe/3r@m0uYSJGsZtmsyMjDbCWx5FiBmTHnJV6VVVqkQg2e95MZzvuCfVgMEgAiOaf@OXfxNQcInWfwdvnzDBMk0WWISe7x@nIIPjeDZiaJRS5jLbgrrup851XBFTC30i/2IX9w@RewUJtKUtPDPmfUAVDkp/vrDbucRLnNtfzztcJz2Al1g0l2FNzgfJuNbi6DCSwlItzOwtRz/luCGxKEuJ9EzSJ8nEA7@VoT9j2JpJOSFKFymFM9lmYrKOMzT0B@oDKFS0UXF1fnaeLhI274PQEsp/JSLCg2HTS4z8H5MxpcYz3NCOVa2juEORKtDNhGhFSoWYSsLl95iENdNVyWyc/JF3sYu5WAQPfmMsZs0R/0s3Kx5vrLRVxEo9dMbzO/mU@P0ZkhmhihS3IxtbwoCjuvXvz9P49/zYwzO2u5jyP4HWd@zWxsZvgRHuDtmXq7zexktjHbxn1mmoM9MDy@@Pt/Q/mdPwEcTJluw5@ddQVrY5rZyZaoyNfMzgY8FNbWoN7/@dvfoA1LvGPDu1iXGp4gxIqKInvNPvEupIsqtpK3pcuxWCHHLITBFoawN4cXNIyarG3mSU2XkVYVt4GMfKXsUeQUT4ZZYzIVYk2GsqeAlREXKGEFWQapTCg6wrDdUGYbyLwxmuLnJ/5GBDuAn6U5h65Sm248idBkaIm3RdCBDtcI@3l@2Mm/srV5x5atbEqKagmJWzspazefFf8X)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/o1mby)

`::=␠␠` sends Twue into infinite cycle, so I moved Thue/Twue after Whitespace:

```
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
```

`#n` and `42` are arbitrary substrings that occur only once after `::=`.
Twue has C-like preprocessor, but it doesn't give any problems.

Answer (score 2):

## 323. [Maze](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Maze), 14650 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($?63_lv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[1140=@$aatq\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(  7#  CO|"14"   #:7 9 7 9              z    7 222222222222222222222222                 "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[7aatxy \#184  O@    <!--     (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++].----._     /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@" *1220*1220L*1211  >" 082",,,@_   2-----2########'\"'##`### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###11  # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*  1 1 v>>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v   >>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>9 @,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o#      #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    11#v1cbbbzcbaaaabaca1tau@.7.8.2<axayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>
 #{{{{]~*[~*  +++++++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++._+._@]+-}}[.^+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}--<^>++[+++++[>+++++++<-]>._++++._+++._^<]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<+++++[>++++++++++<-]>@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  x
#* *#p 173#*  e:1*23/5x%6E2  []-main=-[165]- ###  `. :-write(186). end_of_file. `
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999 Mn MMM MMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMMn>MnMnnMnMnnnnnnMnMnMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`s'''␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9  
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiV=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLzqtqtqtTcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbPsPsPsTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg
#=($?$?0l0c01k1k0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t 0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001k10c 0c0l1111000001 1 100|_  )\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
' WWWw;WW;WW;wv;w;;WW;wW;WW;wv;wW;W_;Ww;WW;WW;WW;WW;wW;WW;Ww;W;WW;WWWWwW;;;WWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ([])  ({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)  (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()))  ((((((((\';  a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#)';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or 1/2and eval('hasattr(zip,"iters")and 200or\'\'=="-"and 241or 1')or 5<<64>>64or 68));"${print(g+91)}$/";exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #< ?>wWWsssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
# 
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164     (exit ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process                            (COMMAND echo 296   )#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (         );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>;
#ceppp  ;  ;   ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323







































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=[ ].pop ?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:window.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
ata#8;&&1Prers>0::geEx Cr Uithary,85"3.c"F ._# gi[s]pogr3461  prstd!\0k:4o $/op>asequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]5:ore>8 4?4在ｕ
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="24 10 31 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001 ""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000 ""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""HHHahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHHaixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCHafyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICHakmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K__aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K__________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
_;
select 192;
.exit
print1(292                       )
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<#
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment;K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_ pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPLdSD4WeX5EckCbwMgUAVU4UE8CLDZbPI2dbubLZJ9@0ogGl0ACkA1gSp0FUACzWaHpNnVWrZ31qORHfJjfGXNelZeT8R4J3bW8o49E2HvxwnHfPIPaD82Nhwb1j/QnnMyq1AgAZAtjyM2NrZIVOXz5MmTJ0@efDcNr/ezn0XwYc@c/rTbd0ZsZHoj1natc9NV2YMpu29YXk7PSBKG2nG744Fpj7ySFGEaY97IcEesb9jdsdE1WQRcdTazd6z@yHSTzDNN1jT7zgX4ZxizzQt2YLesNkBiI@fMtK23pgt@WcYemv13g3cj1nIGA8Nue2zoWvaIfHOMPTPA0hm3zpjR9Eau0RpZjg1eecae231j0GwbjIIPXZNH2mQAqnVGceZ9Cow9cVzPhBSclul5DjoWwdFwLefxztNPr4XX0uxTA5Aa9s3JteQ1jb2wTLd9PYbOPj/Z37/ummGfKY7N9m@ipGXZznjkHIyuw8@xna5pG0xXi6p@3TMPxByZ/UK6kJ7zAr99y4XSNESplWYlY48HTdMF4osivLBGPRUinDic4Myx@1NmTgAY4NiBYOaIWVhaLJdOY0j4PzZbjt2egQcnE@AAXHMwHE2ZwmxH8AB4OS7zhkbLVNpm3xpYI7PN@hZg53QENh6DAmdn5vTCcaHgFc6KhIg3NFtWx8IoIgeehMz20GyOu8wZj4ZjQM9jbcszmn0I1pyyttkxxv1RkjXBD4hH7hc90xYoWXYX8/Fi5oIQbKgCHPt1DWhj9fsM0DlDdDBpj22hxwW6Y9CmSViabQS1NyMXQDL6np/7@YTnksF4z1yn6xoDYNS2STT4/OAZ81qOCzb4YVheC1aBaRkjtrXFontPH0ZZNSCj6jalgKQVdskYi/ie7Nzoj02PDYwppG2PoHIxh8rPjyFBcBZdi5ZYNJNhepplsywLla3A9FyaQZUoggFqrZ7R4JdneoFlNeD7XDSJ6XRco2v1TQ6l6/Q7CGgTOVbPMR3e6SzLaIVokodoUTqbLFNg@U22mWOb8C6yog4JIdQs04o5@OXhB1CKgIUGv0yWpxawBrIUZIPtso4xsPpTDn04RPAtltPYJkAEVDWArBcAQlFHCPNPGN6oB8TtGecAUulbZygyzEBqYIml4JPa2EiR2EL5yJP0ema/j6kCsYBMuQLbhFTzkPEspAy01Au6n/luj7JPeG2m4Qc4bkKOC0DiNFArjeTahB/YQRTpIHN0EDA6yAxdA3cdzBmECuHy4JeH8spnfeh6m2gLEhbiakhMFCoa0gCiQSGwDBRFnmWhiDNYxLkMAzwBgc08A7lS0FghywqbDMhVTDMgvQbIYPlrIM80QEJDYFCsGpSrBohowDAaANUyOSaF6Kpl0B/iZiAukEDLQpwsmKFctDz@IB4UvAZJapCmrhdn7AW46TnIZC5DfKfnofA2wQ@IpQOuOnCLDtjqBfDHuAUgXAHZctMnhNEf9gykBZQAMjOwGhAkBzgRbAgPZn0zw1mKQjfNkdWSriSoWbwVDEsdX4KgFACJwgyGjSgw4Ix7YoEUjINQmhdYY8/sAxeBHGkZYEa2hRqP0sOHY41UlLXQVJnOOTamJALmkvFITDRdbElBZrVN12UYFhpcL0kCxRs3PfPNGNvbGV4dkFAmCNeOYfUDBKjqGCNqC@Ab9SC96TzaHdcZUP0aoMDoO85wiegF8XSBgB45F@YM9Zn0MobDPsh0cDeBEGOjD8hcGKQTkMoQTpUjBJEwXqtnAUBKCmSr5Zotor3IOsTOgBSeR7HE9Oq9DEJ5EGoaMmzogGD1MI497vdL0OSZLZapptrmeQpdePMx32wgDn6DAm2iANE0oD2nBhWxCCDd01Vqqk78kvWcwXzWuHg5CLLes7AZ6F8YUyi9DkgWc2IMQOtg2LTb0HgPgGN4CWJJeLzxOWBtx46OAigXLjSxkOkgJwCyTzQZWQMTdDIHomCJZwlpFG6EWXMKrEzUyqqkknFMrhFKla4TijtkQw68skDj1h63kGqYtmUTB0Gj4FGLVQW4XPFU0QBVzjWNNg@GGgZiFNKRoMUzgehCHWgRINRSTNsDjcdTmYWqITB81@kAj1EzDeoGRJ2l06K8Y84Dp4naUiWiNPLN4KzPLNYaDhm4g44CaO2nC9DOOq8t9hY8@z2P9Vtj152yyRAKwBpAqFHL6XSAad@awx6AYIM2a01bUCshl8g0UtshCdQaXstyYFs3IYxtQrZ3n32ddU2gNrTKHcCUOH2WgeGQskCkMGzeYtsGUAqz0BpOiSwAJojRcRwV3duO6RGPgEYT1HhMzDO7VCOgenVmMmiAGggwJ2gFNrAsCBxRqxA@JigtzAwmJQr/U9OGGtMCZoS6DsWHOukO64D@H2qsUcEzWi1zOBLs4ZAUs@yQUnO4j0oNuSoCmOr1pPX7oI/NYSBBUMnnnFALbpyRcEVln3QtA0Ws6GRAm26bgRrLuEDpT28kDyHOr6Uuv8Iwcxi8kpfgMKSagBoeyYbxCCUICkWr1UMROEIhQ1oGVDJ3fDP74BZO3h0wpROkjdhoIG0kNRU4IR7LYSjw698EpA77CKs654BB5xxuAW14gwWQnQDJfjvsqqYMFWThbUAHju0sgArEDOBikHkfKgtixmOUGkY/YEaqLt5cGaGcnvV/sf2CpnM4dFyoGVzoTFGS8SILcZfD@yqxoImIQ995vkWFliKK7fxoxPtdwz70haiKYU0FfdIASQFCjPcCQOY5PMUQwlTrCZbA74IkPmcmaEJt20SV1HCnHAhkD1plSGjKLNcFMXiObQNvevw2RCU@habAaLdRsiI5qN5fT1xFjt4dN63J9a5GCx3V1550brisg70MF3QNqESxaMeLxsvkTjFDXnLKGY5SFJW/ZQhIgVQo8lgHOi7QEOyDoDme2q2YPFfF5CSTx6NOQY6DASNy1Yx91RiOrmP3GtyQaQZnUK/JVmZdaLUVBd4KuhEm6JFS0cNwQb2ASghadrHYbhrsHUgPlymTXYqNaiF9NTUbpGXa7SAtQQjEJZxflSfhuS0yKKFWDXOAwSnn1EjMEfCOlKCIMjikUqL9RAdS8rgfqTPccWzTEAGLcQ0kzi4DFR0agBghY4HOYbWsUUNoKffu@frKWqUCzAZKFIjNdjys3PtjKSpIagiskhIiElFHzvEI60YsDvnFwFccG9CWgFMrVXY56rlQ48h@JUEgIKtkIyf7hBXl/NQ6G7evF7SNjhhIxloHupLVGsllCRp/Xhsqq6ganaMqKP9RpCoyL8Yn0DeYl1yxQGURzDU91HorApVQCccQA8GrC0nEowq3GUPvTlt9oRJwE1R2Lo2agP6Z6K0HgigpdAK/0t6oqRwIVgcOhz3bOXlUEXWRe6aall2ac@g7LaNPzusYXPbjPj54cLRz9PXGAhh9q1m67pCysoU8NrXjidK1x6msqpfWwzBmgB82VsPGiPNhZEl4M8WZhFSlaQsal4lPzsOjz66TBDQhJAelAGb8XVNpeBhQuqSm4fWuNcKsm0hAkkEUPyxTDpgPMzAg6uhv@Pg8G799i4V3HamhcEfM@mODA/AdUwe2H09Fz2sKmO/V7PAWkeKCFmrZOAY6M4VD@vh8ilrzdWRIlQ6xzKeH@3tHFQLbM7wzs99XKEjKG4EuZbhtFXi@P26b0qIwIP7A1GIJdYY46tOE60ICt1pzBJ6VLVsCHwBgF0d1mNIf@FnzeoD77vW8kavSCjiA7AThul4Z1odaH4toCA9s4lrY013UipLHrLEKnBa2WIHvfLPVyuXMzWwx3Gy1Zmm2w0AHpBRbjq83uuB15inoos60SKFWC/SPH99A3CMlEroCio@Z12cqpeX1Jey9KBaLeqld6KE5fVN9QRJPZnI8lYr6g59qy6M@Zyj83sQaxdJx/tXiEBZS39k50B/6gcVAHQ1gUKcBu@DYMrkdnGxoecAjttN3ug7bgDhcO/QTBLVpaTZ3uo59o4QMdMSsRnD2AuQvjtcYQ2hrrLfUcaRY4e4qn/kwbO8CpLSWzyCRiEIEKkXh1dfGuQHkmuX7@OAbe9CIaLl0OjCn6QEShOIQudDUCrmSA1MgIVXgszCDwUzGjdrueyihqQTMtBB0QcSdmfdCR5KYamph@IUofdW5QfHXzvQaa4ELZy0whEh28PTZ44One092vjgd6bncnD2bLuaBcJBeE3QhtcfphrV1g1dNzBaCi0DdcLF6gRQYQwfFHxIfey4IbhWDqByBJVzD54BiX3V6dtSLX8/MBfoqr@0WZ6EnWPl4UBEROtrtPnZGXD51hu058k9vNBp6pVQKanlv3FSh05p63XL6RjdF8aBh6PdTGnZdDg5xXMNbFAOQ8aYmj8HHtEB1mNLAodEfONB5oek4FA0sxsHTYFXf6vagL4xzdqYbVwMOptyk2tBDgL5yKsgbCWCyAW3F1y8nmbP2VzS9wPlaS@vZlOwHm6v@EHatY0LXKQatFZAifs3KTu@d3mNTkNII6TqQCFM3xLQNtgV9BookDZZiP98nDkkLHCZFWUE0ejPGQVyQUqlcOrup5XMp6JZBNw10VgWH2pSBMWr1lJGjADzF6dC4QYgLO17LsDvqhjD4yILe9wlkNVN7eXpq10FBP71HuOFkWG1ar2n1eJndjLIhwsfLwL1z2UPe9R2Ad8kIrElftkSetY2b4qxtUO1qs9RoMBRtjjJkT3ZAkXrrgLxum@G6hxFSYc/UxlzYFAZ@n1owINTHqBK@kFIpqFDQ0gLrpRAvBZReVA@Bc0BuhSKw2WgGzwefgg7JEex0I99bTtSjsXrUa3CQ1BsCEWmMuYVS2sPxwRG0jgHno5SGwkUhzS7MKA6fGx4fpIRIYuLRjw99tQACDcYHA9F2MOEKTECxqHsOkgP4CkdLe7NRRuz0A6dBgoQTDj6ABmHTpEEX5AxE5hnZ4RnhKZHLfJbObOfCRmhNkxWUpjXiY/zO2MUJPasdzhsEz@g8DECjzIXkOs38Nc0WH2XlkSkX0Ak02MAcODiUANoViQKTsmDwWUPsC3o4UA3VKq3gxAnAV9j9XZBiLZOPFykD7EQBS@2x6MhN7SjfSBnKW@DmFboVZn4nPIlNhX7iE4BGIoNZbBolESOgpJ04Awr0gsZb0POBr@5Kw@moBzkGDpONijM07et9Pt4jjMXLNNcajYLAt@zYZXRtbS1ailajSTBtg2kLTdtoSoBpm0wKmTCciiaKkSQT@tYoBrrVo1c1H/IkXkcemKDm8NYaxoxaqZSpJ42aJr46fuNQFEB5CK3gB@BE45UKGuNxuXqBUzWgv4fyvou8c9xyraEgwVdBIeB2QYMMEQG696jNu2YZ@6arKTKouNBpNFHFjLnR01r6tH56edpOnF5Fkxg7XjYq0D8E4TWKDdSu64yHoLjVsiUFZFu8linVy81KNB3diMUKSh8SMuLxTwrxhMFpHYuawFOx09MokFRQp9bquQRvktTj8YBQgEfHgl5Gvx@LqpcFSL8Zr8cTUYgbjyZBLFeiUaBLC4ngUaZxRIAz0b41AVJCxYQmLjynQAKS5qSwun7DHPambjhAMOoGWjaOoM8m5KEykBQPS8m3PH5YoZvr6ft6Lw8Hyi0O3qG@NJxy6S5xTE9Tc4tD/Hb3XOkMnJGR@lyFTpMaai6ja9GUokBLSD4cEmX7ieVhFTZs0xl74ZHGhQOgmDq4nvTGICz9lTNJ4CprKJmtnsOi6/cBOgumebApwRkrhc97@QDaLRV@KERRK8HJEtAuaEmJBXIRl5vwURmNkOCixx@bz@WHb9QgtTLFYWlMyOrajmsqQBKIIdECEFouJFWZWFVyQCNfN@YlhC81adjxtkyQiPt9xyDacnEdmg8aDkLxoX8OUY7MttQH@dEB8ajysnDNdmpDoslZx@1BCwG5QUmsB6U1EB4pxxu21dEEokoxbHDDnrx3B0rnBWvrup5v5Tol3w@5Aojdg0LCXqkNXVzfS9HAMy4KeY8PC/l99KeHD/f42Ak1tti84jhaY@C0x6BXin7TkWl3k2wP@MmynYEFZPDjvz3rHznOiPfywbJsZIZ3mq3BuG/QmM/1YZmV8VpO0@nTUNCqqLPwY9cz@gYfhPJ9dz5/Arr@85PjiloKBUoZ54OVaeM45OJkOT0PwnOONM3qTw95nDHl9ZyM7Za/IA3FjPDIo8dYLEeDMvLdN9Hdr1I4hyLcC@g@wKVooCuLUQSyBo4iYJEC4vI0XNUjHC@19BW6L@2DBeE0CscVxxm2l5pO7uejTmfOOUPOZwqKpv7MOUvOfJnaXB8xjFKOB8I1a3NhwoDyFCZYunY9nBBewRKDntn3ZxCPQDHBWTJo2/uoPkHfBDVxvn7MBEV6iJMhJKFxio21QNf0bgxbQJ0aKjy0FFmjegJtWAo1F2k9xcQQd5lqiu2IqUmPS08HuvY0erJV5RPW2HVyea8txQff1xsAYqta9lcTLQuGKUWjQTCCSrhBDMomTdvfyGqwCMOjMXWJopQlLwW9homeVk4nm3v1lEdE6DD59HTySVr/AjofuO5r/V6qa5YxuaXUIjsfh271QGywxGSeZFAOY7vj9NsKn/SC8me8u4QFIZYaBCvPSOCDi@X6i84sXMQiFgeCuAytV7sB91rRVW8GCK1wCwBBbbhk786S5@9YDVqwc9Ub9q1RnV2pI6fRw8yPxq59fS0cVyld15h6klipUmE7R59@XkvXOQRpYOBEVoGX1sRfSgl6MOg9uGIVTLjeZmSNqGGnhQUW5ldTAakJzXkA@gCDJ1BmQUIiR4j6O/PdLC8dEzqeMRMx96aDJDPjV2qnb4xGps15i88mLic3n/YRyVQo@W0xh1BiaZpoAUXTQj9AscyOTx7uHR2pwKFeLLqHEzIlqHZGqwf6xrJM@5QMZ77EPmlH2ScYJ469cAmqFHQmGiI@MG8ZmBu6E5A6ioKu6cbAMY5zKS1wpukrisgVLkEgXDXVGhGNAmAxMw55ImClhfg/t3nPSeBZYlGWIEoCuWP3SkBbK66ObeuN6kG7QWooBInyvictk62sx0h8rWtx4h/XGuBcMHSZSAuEPNRqbA2kG4WWWeU9e1lLK8V6Yp3V62U@ww8RUaenZbdiCach6Mmnw0hACpwPRK@sc20hr58CjdxiLI6fBjwrCb4FZN1xc3qzlsrruhwPkFXeggP3lK8juWChKUfRX9pEIoRWQs2vaJpfLxXK1nPqZF9bIA7Z8REI8oPTkDGeS7ZWYVo87mPGAb0wXOw6l9gzx/OsZp9WsHb6Fl8JFjTWJUEYAcmnTDi5MlYMohvWZ6hnWBizZct8MbCgBPlTQwM9KcwZOcTi7BKJSaTUkYrs3Tt0kNm6zogNZFw1zOl75fdpQT4@dgDZx2IVdFjnIKEhlqeg6DiVZL/zNj//iz68Y5A6v6bzKudyOB7XOS37zKFZpMDUSKtaDvXMIPbgrH8zZsfyevSaCxrgwMPqy7DzBs0OvRYEoMkUMU1PDjRMLzRsKE4jdUQfGrFfkPL80pS5ZJtmZ2x3aU4TzUx5c0tIpVigwJ1m01oWFIiAq83874JgICux5ulqVtX82oMDPNAsgvzkfaJZ1q@vamJzdIdGagSxxPc/f7MN9L9ZOj1or3A8MzA0QFPAklI6SwtLREULvRYXLB92H/ctgwhDpttAtgwXsmT0A8Ni0DS1ryigbwxwokKUOPAmvkAXXcFmHHM@z@h/FyeyaKrOBrndWhb22iovnhRNKkF3sU1E4DqXZVIkErK8EMwJn9gJddxR4N6OlL8UixEz83LvjUdj/gZ1@NZCtIb4W1U3Rch0zmhqJnRIjaZlrihy1zgbtx1leNYN1OL8grCz3NPMsgJaiZhkbqBxcfZ5Bl2rC829/10WbNa@pi7ocxtXePbYGypN6tu3uY0qwmBFCm6fv5cFscRupcCwnGpWn1535EQBHRhFrLFI4QpWJUQ06xqZ@0ZziqpQ7@O5LFivABKn0kok0pklE9bD4fL42D@l@MXi4tgTtcXpsWjkIcVXySp8bI4yLNbN3lKq0FxZA6Ov6O2QcakwX7Tc4UbQYKaU4pjnOE90vrDkZtTHBqk17hvuzLSCxWd4@JMTy8a5RbMh6nLL6VseVuj@Mqnpr7mbpYXrlOkVWldhLaJkGzqi2I4rgWmxFHBaI1yLuoSt7iDT@BpQXGkb4hPVWUaslnOBv6UaRA86w/y9uFF7uxCrO8gnpd/qG9CUL20R5kYdcVTzFl69sDyTXosJe7YQ0VGrv9B9vhb444nh8cHbONuz@o7Hjum9ikBdF6jA34t5OkxLy7AVGmUPm1eIIX/xxKxAjX7X6ecL3ZQBr6WlPnY7KPrF965CLhBSmnaLkPI1IMfWxHepaD9LuWe3FRDt/3Jx4WzIuKKVXSSpxKTO8txB3wBnBBfnbD9doJhqio8hLkkY53IujKn//Tlaj2Wk9VuP4ZQ0alDwMEKxAIaRy7Xsnye17OrU2ncTSjfAbt6WiVDhnvVNaK/ofaNImZ7WPjKGlk7fXUR1@mNzbC7saxw2X5u4lXhFP@PuSKVFNtbFFADOOuCelyDUW9E5vBPW2FSjbaUwMaDXbt6uzcwLtSEo4EPsPT8DwzM03IzRtcfDuVKd66DZR6tJ1hv6Vdppz2GHPh8rhwq3KEtzKrpn0m9lp4l38nDlWSWbTqeFDhOaypmzrOpMZYK4ry3@nkuYXGYpz8Li9J0bMi5Og8gSXtu4VATpy/r2FLhYTNmWbY6m@L6jNG06Tv9jSgqEattCbQyUS1rDu6rEbqg7YncKm41eeDjm0ewsG7fgrY3oXgJ9sN@8qtDDc013Kk0FZ1MHONM1b109ghOaubotFdzSjcNCfFVvf7kuKQZENLWgbq6sdVxDdZpm3@CfST67Cl5RzayENy80xCwwzhrzueLZHH/kmlAaToFYVhs6Kj1zYJJ1haJvtF@PPf@zNNDEwd8y74lptlKTPbO1LMDQArlg43tucjqkLI0cG7pYI1xAiF2VPi5RFa7LJLA/nbiQyAcDo2vycypWScrZmAUu0@E9u5lx8ehFiS/NaUG02QjzcpaASnVmTj3/uxDgk2kLynU8uH3E7Vrlb@Ew6B1q@7K1sTebWLvn9Oye2eML0gPbssoB/Dji54qsQh2w7vZwjdxwOLd2PkzPvtPv34WeKBq5oHSczkKc9nBXLW4J@yi4U6MJHuJz6/idMeKyAw1La03PHEO75DkjZ2gqZFsWtI9jPfy9TIb6s98/7yDSyq4@UMT//rzwb@1bdg1nNBzSpzHsjz16UVSFNkPfpjd1@JoXWm3puF31rTNoqsJRFQtiaNJ9sYhpWqNWDzehc842u06z1bNuQ7ppGiPbOkv5oz7ceqe@K1LGYspDdFb7FpDXnarIL5Ww/zF@DpYVuhhA4s1aYFihrywapKP93srQOGt5fEAUTayEY8Kh2sh3hZdoO33pzdgazYCGFkkFI7x8ZgINy3AXyzKWala0@WImhsVyjaVcSko6KuSKmQaFR1s6vjS3gC5UxTIZ/lqGUDiXhFFowcvHkFssKqIBQis0dAvuc/w1txpqYSNn98Zd76bA5CP2bVDR8LV82IIWSYdGraHNMmzxWUZmvZ/C3ZPwbYDONTZXTqvkVs6rUDitrxiOBZ8GfKDoxkvH0PrW0ONvpnSWzsaJRVLQF78@ZchpM13cmRYF0zY7fBYETbepiAOH5mlBB1FaOKePg@gozLnixQWX7XRBqCt9Ngvsh12mtixcf7S4@IM2U/niqdk1cBH3Y2uEq0AXcAWx7KJ1S7fC/trY8KyvjSFny5gNj4LgM5Fu@MwAtC2A98ToWq1HcwURICkILJaQ8s8c@6PTzbK46FkerqEKDCsGppDlOBMj1zWg37Ag5PWh@@AUjFkF4vsrF4ZeNLzuDKe4DW1KplUj69aIRlnFd1nXcdnqspVIXIwHw7EnPotxoFVa4VHowRm5excWAFfegGhlPaM/WjxSHRpyBS1MNIoz4zJt/BtW3@mybxTSDJQ2UMJQOV/AOA@geX6GS4NcewEnUtp3nPnEgQ7F5Rl7A2VrZphi2dZo9WjOaITLhPwvZoa3HLj1IfUY3@r9j4WgnCymyOPbdf3Znudb2nfgvGNn7LZMNAYHmYS7BSJVc9df1oxbRRw8iOUi3EtbOXsDzaFjj0eKO7ZXtgr5la1CiU0K@RAbsNjX9p48j4e5gZaB36aFmtD5G3v96cy0dM3ANSazbFDElsvR@dB@X@IhP3fpiNYg3xJnBw@HapG4fugs6u88m7rm6M4dJhD@48FDs4Uzh7em/dR54tgOtEZDEJSDI5MfJjC31mNxRIz2GLfLA33atyZzTGCXNEJc2zCGZhPKtz8z3aUt4oAfGiNjSVNEY4PU/wtMt/KK1W@a7msa9AuZl3Vp5xF6ZE6ob7GcYXgdVEatFleJcTxuro7Mzdh4Q8ex@ZukbRo@2pPVUgWaAnrdfa5cxRX@c@MCC/tn81k9POcLRcw2P@1iWV5ds@n0@XvFsiTb4ssCDNcyvdRjPDyB3PJZpoD25a2UIZsrZcisawSa7Lnh0Tz94q7GDKQ2@YhVQD3DbTk4EyYMKxbohE48uEVMB5sG@NqBJhB@AhLLaI3F2Yu3odUfNAf0WtphCJXmkdnE7UZNOiZkZExuFiYfGRJnJIQWdQUnC/jiCit1nsWeQW8kfnuzNdePmqeqNaQXSeql0@W0XkexLbP11sBRM4foNRubnvOHPKeeknHJWHWoGtEocsqgLfQLa9L86jVQaPqmMuq50OdPjVYNb/vntyyYDxkPTJxknp@FWaq6Ol6PMussnk8PhKtrKuLsQJAlwTmCXD9UdpZqngge/g8ffDUFjXAjn/XPNAHRdfsMPiA/dm3xuQsHPnO8UceaHALeuO9gmTjBbOUgCnx4zUDTxrJMQOnZ4z4ffeiGll4N2tQdU@gMW0Xpk7gemYppnyt0wtzkZo4cvpsstYOHoY7MtiIOWMCZBuWxv7EsCCa@CyZQw7IR13tqKU7YST4rVoAuIu6FLxlA33JGytCjb2roPTt4fHiiDj1tYfu008P9GDf0uLkTG/RCOjQk9dpwQ/OdfEVa2/JGqQfHmrL7@EDFAEvozWc0FPjgzNzcZ@m4pzh61EgZS3tB6GuOFiuIj06ePE7M9n6y2G7PdQZmPOy9e3ycxL0tXz1e6B2OvQ@1o@NMlkY/2NO0@AL2fW7T7OAy6bkgpWWQTkzojQIzPuIHvtyqXLWcodk@mQ7Nz6HxRAnu3TH5/NJMPjXOrS7WQlZcSiiqqKyo5rPx0OJs6GybbvBdVp5n1hClZYs@Kf5ZuhwFNYdMys0s1h5Wzfhf12JYWqxE@LhIWvomt44sBWpGt4emlOH9QxHTNG0ZnY@NDpQryy0trPkAi@aH@875HaaSTdF5UQInZQRcpVi3LiXfVAYgulP4wuF54QjG5tJlMKsABM75hRX@wrSnhq3QXNYq9aIEsXFR28og3zDvMCEVrPA5xwOhF87xBavqWaxFxvgtCZ@4oSi7uw8ObotwJGi5OtSnT5@zZ4aHp5usDhjG2LwDxjPN6LWC41Z4tN7S6dS2C6D0lfC6w8X1ucSODbft2NPJ7ZNwtLkVm3Y6rDiAhTYKZPatibWorWrxca1ni5cZ3ZY238fhTOf04PCpNwLQh@/8c01Lp@lMI/xqaW69pWT8Cs5iaDKmeFBe2OvkIBANLdRbVHCIL@yNPjYnuByFjwYv6tQvbN/yK9q@zfjy5mSVX2GFX3ZFejf80JFl1LS2AmBuhR/LqYH3Y6d/0XPUXcM1vTuWSQi1VVkqrshSMSSn3xbSOBxKU4zCvFzZx30M4rOQb0/MkZsd9pymlb0lNzsdPNGSPcED2W@tZLihjBa/dB2xJ4TbF@NwMb5NQj0x3q4MwjeNHY3t8DHGXlIcRMH3evLdd57qnzUdi9mJRDw@f51BeK8h32WHh93xDXIQ9t07tib2wYFHsDVQ7L7DM7FAKTdxz6pEIHBTZMyuVLRckW3jpQIlaHLjlCI60clDflo1tn4pNrWVStoVbuyTSzITmw6Dg0T5YZgAF4/xgzwx5Uxj6yPwWfe3xDE6zp29Y6TGg96g5dJgU1PhPcplsVcQUFq/fHbwbO/4ZOfk@XEtXb@S42JHLMfNtiE1f6/0J5m2DHkXZAPxwI/GpT21fUiOjppH9d/z88UgZ9eyVpnL2ixT8jbGWb@07VSKtoamlCvAT5F5auQLbT06cdh@jql8xM7eEt9R2SeSyusctExpQpmVWHpRwkMD2HrdFv7XL7sgX5bJoC9PWJxmCizZdZy2SNEz2e2Pn@L@zsHj50d7zEdwxjQXVnvUqxRz/LBbbEIVE8qpY9EqkwqLiihRKKtKJbofBcJE1Sgr0YZcOmgW@ByC@dTBrbwi9gaLrRN8oGA0KJTUf/5m6iqq4oLJOISN@khFmaA8BmAnuMnuz3/c5gex@0dr@Le6uANqL@gIA0lsoF2yfRYpShVzuPxuFzr4nHbKBieuz@7LkegcfuDKCzoV69qJSXE6xIRf1CMOtPITIgbxD2/GkTc8nMr12LmF22Q5Dh08K2qelXGyns5HU9kOXlwDPM8MugwAUB/bI34eizi9IQJ8pAYCJcnWCVl@dYAcChjdWgNWbppdy2aeDd0Zc1Rir4HPcHSrxPdqK0o1eiOKD5rfWKT0RoN@KOCNw6W81Oko9eFXv5vqlhmYJ@kHYPtlYeuA@Ve4@WUKy/rmAVSz9MNI4KFxAmueeEBzpHfojh6b74mfEQvPyfIlJbMGUDTnRGkMzlPgbwUE7AxOrPY5FBSwGJSS2AvP0zPdegxPrSulUshG2ByqtP7XnPDFONdOr8vn8lktBUgq5z5AOm66ixsNOcB4vASML51bw8qrJrDX1haTUTs2K/kyL83Uuv0yI78KEF2HsNJFD5GrMYgDUWYxwK8qokFzktDiGBXlUVSLoihqO9DOkD@2R2i3BSFkFgNicRqZeH7xBC9rGrlT/xTGJl6AFLqKYF0AUjRoZcgUlyWxffupMwKWmdu4zrdv42I03qbh8WYev4yMDj9EHlRv1qbZrkP/zgNRv1Ss9xxUJn29eQyXrfwCQRwjiJK8iGVrL9np6NSupzhvMmDTHwqWDTOzDeZfSnWX8CzP987No@9i1w@uQ2Kx@8e2g92AfcgMi@kpPZPS8vFZlrLZhVkSORLJQHbwQI53kByIJhATLdN67Qy9nd29g68ePju@cbwbhYxeDwaSvLqVOFXUZK0eGKLhbM0XyYP91PGTB/t@QcyQzockMGgvIifaqpzMevcIcrZa/HrWFmF4PXfLMX7Bt5Rexzejr0KNIt3AQ0t/RLq0YlPZp30X1xPXC4uolcutQmkGLxUCvcs3zd1ANRa/vKrVt6qndiR6kxMWVISXEXUDKwGYTr2N9RQy@83MYcaCSwNP8KojL1wXM4vroryewVOGcNvuyDmbna8kHEIeofz6yYCIlNSUH3Rp7TvkWvfsFDCdX2rIzyMKn8ISQjifXkXxEKgT/35ElCKzMwzF8X096GP3rabkn37Dj/HzTxsLTvDjJ9fE4pI4CZ8nHBM3Jk5KE5WWZ8TiKO0IVpKtOhHQhxeXoEKjvvZsDD2fZ86Qn4xM03APTd905ID4fTjm8/km@@p4AOE69DkyaUgUJLcCkYGS0QBVrj@BlBAHAk4SeOQipFfDYwFFxtVBOxebxNWeOWlbXZDtsXgSJNonmlZnwaGBmGk6JNCOylRms1JYWRU/xa2QYbJ/1MmRkxkCRs1QLbttTmLRi2i8VIf00T168eI8GpcX8RKdYCmOdGxfP8oyQH9TWy1JjJGonf45kYukRbF4U0qA23XA/Awm/1qWYlHteRLdrlVBXfx45D4GI6gRsc7AGLLY2ObnVKmMrLHTmJ2kg32UKj/qzmaJBHWR4EMeKqOYHTLx9jtm2FMWS1WACdDVs9v4eWsNWU1T1TqYKZE4W8frknZB48IzX@IS9GohSonAVpCFoOMAGPFKonIGhzjoL@FRPC6d9rXAm26PoZEjB2lCuWbVeyx069W85igXiyVRoPNSsciA@26KQzUFYG/IOV@XB@qKMyWAZtChVaXITJDflHgRSjfCEXkkDqMAdCKh4yn9MyoYwJodHtnqufiL7dlQV/BYndLzk/1GIZ6SWXCoRde12jiyyU9YDjpt4k4MqKapuaDRMu@jfYrR8LSyBj81Aw/T2qcKI18TqZEwGa7fAzvjTU1byfUioigFCJnFBkDs/Gn44PBYPn@OeYHfYmH/s5/hTbNybH07n2n0zxPRXLoML62cYzn2yfqpoqzXNC2brtxfN4zRm1OZGansxsNzs9dpHnRTp7LMMiybSm1E9zeeWXr@5ZvJVUYrvDkbavma@mZSlwuV5Fl9wp49@@J9431cnpxP5dMYY5sRxnYP38laFjurkdImKzL8zT1v8UUXQS58bvTS5ajMIqeneIOsvCmnUrVoHf7J6xU8PFCtqlbV7fr79/HaJuRpMmWnEbyVkR3eR2/qJ9FIk67Hjy3LSrHTodduw8/psTq/WjjCn0QipjDhoNS4W3kw6ZDbZMfsdsd7xpS7W5ExfvZHIu6Tb7x48QINL@hhb48iAjaH6KdRahi5CNPT@p//ZO0qefmssfXn3xqkzDX8HOLnu1dP0Hys5T5ZW/vkwYNsNgm04eZn33j29Z2dnezDZO5ZLbedVdJrW3/2p2trur6lp9bqnqfVo7Wzsy9kPZ2V1T//UbTx7NnXPK@a@T@@@b6q4WsTXudYMvhkmAZGfBfgp6GOdcbewnPWYfhP5rftkNlAc7PzlkXeRoDLtciU/hqRoMzWmFbd3vwv3z98ExlFqnrqhQvfUeRNJF@IcCMYwJbxbeeRamQLg@WvItNUpVIB4@Z/@bcQv/pVgIM@0y14VXM@rPw0UlUqFOVdpJoHg6brkO7/9c1vhpiHi4kKqXH@c5/V4JGzm7q8XYdng54tCY8SU9Kp1DX@0wr3tHuM2aPeyHTwY/GPbeKZzkoZet1HtUQiUVcVeNQGRUppmn4KAoDNsRaNtxCVhJW7sLBbwCfCBfxeRIingKmIr7hZOBCrcYcX18O9WPCUX/xjP0dSJL9233xYrYIozFQzG9UEPWunpRInf4ptFmTHuS@zDSizNL0ewxvpVZVZuqDLyWTyPlJSR5oquqBfJHoqRyORVzOS@pSNsJmNhZ3oTQXBZmGWhWNscbg9fP7if/2LH/zF9@nvB/T7D3jqmt22OqkNRjXnvMofVq3KVVe@PCULZDhdKpQKqcbVaWwDJFX9iGnpT99Fc5noMbYS9JzG/RHOSPBUq/iif2EjE32vuQmfamChELMoq8Mhp1G60ASLxWlK7Rywqc5ydOMpsvtQSrK@WZTrVT2nH1bltCbzcuute8wR4iCyDc8a/NE/PIF1DUeR18htzfehUDeftUUYcPKufqRIrZaqm3VQZFmQjftrpbVCKV/SU41lcBF0eWFqIO/OtVaz2XzbahrwNI2WoY2M8X11Uy2o@pYxMabGqDluTpqj1rilaVLkfW2NHfFaUGcJ/zlN3Po8V9WGMJLBwZ@iOJOIFPlHeKoSi1zCU3@/UXsPTC2SrokanNhS6tWEwAg@auN@PaFcXdXUl4lyWfxvVQNjmR5ugozUrxRl6yXAqt2EyoHSW2283AKwia3aVsXZpZ/aQOIr9ZfV2tZ8XBH9/v0ESt/7AKC6XmfRrBPNO/dZPJFYV5S12tI8AOA66C1bW1C0V1tX1ava1tXV1hb8b9H7SnzB9Wrrxj99Zs@SMDP/Olao01qqepo6FQxVB7uaqqKLmjoFQxW@EA4aKCkCKstEimywjciQaZsZMDGzpG3omVRu8kl@D1SlWl3Bvk1FqWn5XF3hMuyVykoKP8RdK@TjKgqphtNp4L5Llb2SIq8@fPk/4@/0w5d/gBoAaGhFKZLawI5Dkfcf4PXEZk@ePMHfE9uGf/g94Y@NLujwxK4@scmXO5DhiR9KOHOXuUqJgoPJeiEvNxLaVGeRLTm/iaLjF2480Wj0n7zSi5tR3s3GrYqvPHD8hUXPP/mFZY8UeVdEYdDyGM@eFIESiShKVYpUtwa4OA1HrhXsJHxe@UJ5vqNgr9YY0VxEi/fYKgd7lWKxygfd158RC2083IC3Bv97a56HF3NiMpf4ar7Bv8dv8e/NCP9OWvh39Ab/2Mlb/Dsa4R970sS/Zx7@nbzBv50m/p0M8O/BG/x7MsK/5138kyIVUO/Xt9P9dCutnWlnYLBY2mXpXrqntTVqj9ImS0/TU5YeOFobTCb8pcFkpTss3WVpO21DMPAF04ilR2jqwKcLfx0A5MKfhYsfzrR0i0FCfWyp6IYnSiCdfgeyPn4q1aDnKr8yQRtXNTWt5q06Ho1fk@t6scBULDO1UXt1Gq3jmat6McuaU3Pt9BWLeKDJlyOp09MUH5NgeraMp@hfXTUae08fNhoplHOnT5zD2f/h4SBsXfk/OHSeHDoDB/4PDw@fMLOauJ9Q7sNTqSa2xGc7Ui1vn5YUFAq@HIqktrZPqxkFzfkEqiDolvjIZwYRvtW1UynKQEG6KJMaVr44L1@UyRBYwdAoBwFEMG4Ax7JQ38Cl7OtxF/CcX5AjvtB48eI0MHFD6sXFKXZHoJ8Z/IOeG7b@V/i3/t/1/@Q5i9XqoFbFLq@2YvTE8S8ev7y6vBLvajwWE5bYFvyhA9gxyuVVFY0U6BJMtVi8Hr@64m7wjsW3OMAqprFVpcizgCACIkGalC5/xf7rfjFt8Zzi6ezGbIHA6ekknY6Xm/5p0Dg5Zryjedp4me72WW/WtPqf/YjO/N6OU6BctlzWNhi36Fm9XM76ts1CuVzwLeuxWPHmU01va3nQq7LZeLxcBsu2DzYN1gBsAcD6lhxANT2jRfW@HLk8OKTTsEFM5CJxzBEXDLE0HZqP969E5ZJ8715M3Ou6vRO/d08vpt@9C1yGQ3DS5pwajbblNhronnn3Tm7INGFfzIE9XXj3TksXE1o07rixp3hxDyQVUzT2iV6lVIuOC6TYBG@mpfQZHj3DM0YjN/bWGiZlXMrlyXG6VyOddtzT6E@/961vnUYrFVmRyTWrIQBMheW2tvLZajWfBXO@ALSS1y/5FTPdRFGLX62nZE4PJq9HI8JLK2zGuXSMoj@0mmy7ClXcw@fyKkLlzrK5eAzEaxzUuKsI/nFnrVjk7tl8rJAoir/KWrwK@gX/w15xJpHd2Ny4X2f0N1n4oEguX5oV7apyaZZwdPGq3BJ3JuLOT/PevUwRaFpIl0@lRuPhzslOo1GRZRkbRXihIwl3Ca9qGrrRGhV4rlivYe7qp9FoqXyfmEMr5FgkWhbhlCi0EqxQJCJIVge3dXsekzQx5rAm6fTFlyRGndbAMYKtsvhJkWePd3b3TpL6FqhL@v7OblI/fv4goqE1N7OTdwbtR3s7Dw@fQ4Rnj/d2jvc@Pfh87/kzcPfYxezxBbB4z75h0wL7BXshvXbfGqZpmGPTbFyMxxdv2GvLalhA1/7Ysiyn6zLPbJimOYRg/lOGX8vyjNevDXdID/vww@98@OF/8@F3v/fhd7/z4Xd/8NMvf/Ad@P0Yft/j3@/9m2IO3z/98p//3off@V1w/A/w@2P4/eSnX/7GN/mP7H8Cv/8UcvsT8QuF4z8JYP3yT7/8/o9@@uWv/Cb8/qX4/ebN36/@ZPHvB99e/sN43/@91WG@92/h9/sclh/2e7/D3fB7I/zv8HC/8psffv3f8f8/E39o/N0Pv/4n@BKWf/abf/afPnzr3@t64c/@9Ydvf//Dt7/14dvf/fDtf6p/@I1/raXDr9/78IM//Os/@v2//qP/gf5/TO/fv8v/h9/8Z3/5v/zl//aXfyR@P4HfvwPTT/7y3wPP/t0f/hD/v/@Hf/fHP8T//@lf/d0f/trf/fL/SIbf4ob/@1/@G/7@m1/9j3/729/96598829/7Sd/@1t/@Nf/@6/8n7/xH//mv/2Dv/nvv4WOv/WTv/7jX/6rb33nr779L/7qW18ueX9n5fvLO7h/@Y/gcnc87wLnLvn6WJcvfy58/iHUmKUCfALc/UsffuMXgcF/nbEP3/kxLl@G35L/H@sahfkxt/1/wKDfzDP6pMEEv1/78J3vIYn@OyAR/Af0@m5gmfPhlu/OLEDW314Q6Zd@@uW/@BHZImapSgPJ2IwW9EJiA7oaG8WiaErFGDNE@cV5aAEAkdJ3UULN@X0XZduHH37zw4/@6Ycf/taHH/4yNmRKtpjcSSra6tEvaPmU3B3CYcD8XcJhwC8w/QQNzCqJL8DGvhCeX3zxhdR4l8J18vffgesX5MQfxr1wHb3w8v3QHRfWs3csbBbGtDCuC9cgZcICU02QArDhaye5DJskBEITHPbDL7hDoMkGGSf4Jlf0nkj4mv3PjBOJJTAMf/BmId9IBhFPJMGNUg6SSUwmPrlIXWJcRdngLjRlRelmiwxzMJkkJtAPBQOkkACvBwlWqVQSGLHC8QErR61aYIRKIlGBfGNsHifZKCCIyQOCAjEriSPW2KhMeMQEwqv65EhI6HQka7qcKFQeQoKVyUOGsBA4gX31qlItVCZVBPee0yMxSTwgnBBYJTGpvgd7hWAmcJzq4XtApVBJJKoFTBAzyYsn2eCFlKPMUd4TLCHKAL44Crx9n7FPZK0g8@mTNSQYD43vxCz0Ns3nbYP/aWJDZIf@fSP9Nojga5SUSIVx/21SELe5zogBAK6iqKrK4IeThNvsPnhPOKgEJQufBIeQII4gDggcgA2xLBJUvgmyQPqRysZHPwgMM7O@vi5FqnJGPqTZpAR01d2zEr8Z5h3vD5WYnC/K6GzSKnMfF4hfpvTXozgwGGUcMPskwX/372@wTyCb9J25SUxJZJwsDtkjlK1EQtYBftVJSC@hZyABnxKgd5I6qdBsVUJKJhlTKxH0Y4eHhwIJcnhZkRLA5npGQztOL4zH4wjEUNWkmkyKr0pfclCFQSVf8VXXkbg0kMl0PVuG3kuZoRML9zY06Jai4/v376FUaKlH6QA6jEys@tCzBfIEB75NuN@f@rsR9GxR4r1lpuX5Le0xusQxzuISi7GNuMQXBXMk/CcW1QuFKJriQH01tuEvAsprxA44shipIqL@wztwhVzc99w9ZLuHT57sPT0Z1utMMul2TbMxdJ0W7upY8cQw3s7Th3zPgF7MIxqRWg1TPinpKH@kvVKapOPBw6OD4xLjNBElFAsgxcs0dixIUdSkyHD4YisiFkrIeN2LIx/juzTLf0wvZjDBalmKtEzsdgDD4T8rS0@87gNnAl31pCwntTz2wOI05MqkrztjhgeR8V3LUO1wJbm6tUVEkqqXCo2QoxEKNC9Vq2KFEdOk6vHeCUQ4OWSanlal6hdsomJyypVU7Vf6pt0d9dZxqY58mpZDWVqvpZP4p2cy8Nay@aSW26yvrfUvFUzzlEr2EtdcXYH1UsFMfAUeJn1FYl8BJ3ggDVxIxcQqtoPDslhKhEd@xPh6IlnLQU2MS6fACxycNAw/5SHUAOiNh35SZO0b3xixahW6wcrBvhQBidJj/nIaxWqrPZVYoT12TfLtMta2PrfwHh@1bXnDvjGF6gXkiFxdXXUA0sE@06s6WXmMNr6vWuTSBPPVxJAidqlUea9lN6WsXiq9z@i6BA5S5OVLw6hWa@n6ZXZTz@ayOT2Tz@c2dSBaMZvPFTJpLZ1P53RdK2azxUJx84rFoGQNQ6lWMnpG@v@fOz003bA1rAI5t1JDMBpgzG6lDDA2wZjbSjXBaIGxuJWywDiuZrT0VmpclZi0xU/dYriptyKPzAke8sfd5Kpn9jsqbj@oyJSALm@JUyyrIl4V93E4RruCOz9x/X0sfim1K22nRTeQSW216bSnqjea9nGdft9xK1HQvqK@h4WXuuJ@uEqN1dWhM4RWUs9tJmpaGmQ1/rRCUk@21VbfNNztXClXQEswibKdS5cuLLvtXKhfPHn8aDQaHpm0FWA7Wyy1VTxaAzfBbxdKuVy9VpPlRI2SqeOFhryWK2trUDNMo63At@PYI0/RC3WI3LbcSiUa3c5ouqKVMumCdBVkXwLCYZ6qEsZMYF6SSLxLUY1KtmNDlS0ljaR1SfkudTqdq43LxMwiGZcKtwFFrhQj2bwMrGUlFK7ExknFmnmCi9GBRudSzCCVZD1XkMu18sy@mZfL9Svp/sBsWwZuADhNX96MlQfRxqFGIKFTJl2VXMcZlZpmx3HNWcCMlvcDcoRuBsjKV0Fyp2lM8fJmcnkMBDTklANO5WecVWnRWw3EQH0P2slafcs//Qw5VNcVPaNkNEXL4P8tBh3/7x5eh38d3xAro0snuAP4KQhlaEhs9hj3Q44cduI4dK/eA7O1JMRuz6DVfbuu43n/gDAPDPuMez20@LFbgdcjAy/U8AbWqLckxPPhALdOmu4/GoS9QRMQpIpNAR7Ay@07zqIAm@z5syW5fBIcdAnE4CddQvCjg08fnYS@J3s7u4@kPHtw@PThtU9OBMqxx3v7J4F1k/v6UXMBiK/vPX583So@2cPnR52x4@JP2j98np29AifcMCZl4ZkPFDgTEPFCK7T5ZRqFXmO5Td@gSbjk@B70zu4JYy4/M6bR@ILvhrO8YAks3/ZYkk78LXIGQwHUNFmL75DF7iKd3yKUSW2zKElDZjsXbDPN2k6/b@A9pZ01cOwZuPXHRHWpT9fpYtIXjttvX1htc016gruMihpexohISI8AyGDcosMSrJGEp4G18QZRnMto9scmG@MtvUsc4YNOaHStbg8amAvHDyA1DYPRKpePeyC@GX5Gqx1GPA1yu@HTvxlcikjGyIgUyvfuac9cqCnVdKnUNfcmwKXsOdQaw50mCzk5o7bkfaY2Iqxr1bz6EIoqk81rqGmBdrt2mj4rZR22nnKGVcOD1iiRrYGCOOq0ytDG5UpAZehvZ7ezf/PbP/77P/01kHAbKXhFNFnGBc5rmqSS6qwXC7lCMaMXkoViIZvT8rlcUtOT0DPZLILmmdYKWr6QK2rJQraYAbYrgm@uuClF@Oqx1AaBhG8JwNotvCNwi7RvtVeVInwKi72NGXEWMQL7mMkmxJHxVnhvRDsoN6yKrGeZlmbQ8QKIBmuxyP7@bnp/X5YfoAWn7nfTstxGS66QTm8@kGWTfHYLqDXIDo9TwKNW5BG3pNMPdmV5zAHgKaWy3EPLXh6Hc2TZQsvuzv4@ptNBi47xIdgZ9@GWvm/ZhGA2WjIZWkogy28CcBBuhyeUJUz30IJpos8@99kFP1n@1McnnQYIRzwch/DIz@vOjiwfcMvODvrsUsZzHNXP0LJDjyy7YIE6IMtdMHRdqH2y3AQj1gRZboGpNTXADW9kxKMs7ZEhy1NOICSRLE8otNE6k@WG747JPHr0yOiN2maXP1OXf1uAGvhYk/HefvPTT5vdbtOd7ux9eoQ@u7uPjM507Da7TRGt2YDHgTjgczaYXn8Ax4NGw@gv9PkMfOxrPo1pw0TcGsYbwEk8XUxk0NgFn13wWTT7x6HBM4CgTXweDOD7wGiSj/@QD30nzaZcRkZFxZWuVYY6QzccJwdGy3XKaJ9U1hiLxqLJaS2frpfJgw1ARU2Xr@g@5Ri@DRwoiF9Oa5NKul6ZVDZ1vmykE5NPJ3rOkpNrg22tmCutGduank1MSriP2ulEWVTRtllMu7fxlsWexrf1TLYkn25vK3JNq2/rWqGU33y5MZbleAnf25nNEgRMR6Ebja94bbO@vZkLRdncTBgpvbS5GS9fATlG0Po2sQPfiMUuTOMsHkd0sa8IWeC3OU8pn1a5E5skJxWOF5vGy5OKVuanrLH0DVhtPNJz3Bo5LofYBXCT7XSJ7ouWtWJBhvRTqVg8DpKJhAh8ZyvOXnzt5Ozk5AuQWdCxFn3YZ/wS0rKwfvpoV4VurbDhUZzqPnYQHFfdRcEy58NPivSdTkCLVh9Bcwd9CN8N97a4Tl/dm7TMIfYyfA//gDVVHIulnjyag3MMHXieMm4NLtPJEnbLZHhSqdVmRqUKJqPNYoQVM@IX1NA2qtVKozLgVz5Xg1ifMTrGcwbmwOO4BxuWKfol7vcQHo1K@qrcrEwiE4DTqDBFezVw2q/0RKvcxgNKH1QeYORyA77Nslkx8eJrOSKXO9t2hbGx7Rkd85np4vb7g8N1aPZxE0isw8z4Ojula7J3Ude@Uqous2eYPR0PYtCPbsbnnUJWJE3sa36WL2lXEs6nX5U7FRZ7GS@/Aau7zmJt9UF8O1tuxx6wRhxc0q86rzpMZ/lsmW4OjCEkqEREG7p@Ol6pfgaaCgd8VioBIqKMzwAmpgRgrTZ5GPGhdVVuVfosprAJixN5suVupYax3@FrS5HluqLU3tWlqqK8kKpQT8vTiFHxxk061Zqlm5qezpcn4KZtZss9KFjj5aTsVoZj1yz3wSoGdPjmK6MM5ASqAZi372IffvGb8S0lV@FuZQL1rg/KQUNtVCZlG8/JAZaoZCrgkahl00nog8JrMwkNsp5PavlkJplNKpvoCq1xMpcER@iHQKMf68dkxuRkepJWtaRmaslY@pXVfhVPnsVAuSCSsXhy5OzhrdvgAoWEXElW@BosntA3@gxKwWHGlkJsCpKijBkDmvfY0Er2ENSRafQpRjyusMxGrL8ewzDrJ@PhXq1eKu1Nhl8Dr5jyZjuf2Ewn3sbj5dhavAIKilQtS1WUKpTr4RrwrBjrYt54UIMyHq1rm3qpVmtiDjfTyUw6A5mzGu@6W3JVrifTa3kNSuiKkR7DuMDgusxMG5m5NVA7xivsmVbUy5JKCy8oRS2mF/UlQ5RxCZf8CYDSUAg7pC@Lncr@9sNYNLqpR6PxaBmHsNdkMR4JEo6kWxREbfSeti2D/iSX5KKOAWaCknaYpcMq1JWEPXqWLUqRS@nq8moLuqQpWoGHCuAamRS1el@KlBgDPe5UnGGSWmPsYxf2JbaqL/n3FNcVA1yJzrkDtZFW25gW9qPY57ibdptFATHDHdR0PVOv6ZvQvoHM9IPqulbGYfsILmBWq0B57xLw20pUcSPKZ2w6NRKKT9l7jHUT6xJlOnKd7DuVne7RTtm37eKw46kky3I5Kkcuo5HoFfxJkfu0@0Xnu19YJLT/BYemcVQX6PM@QhKD7V76w0UlvG0lZpS4fKjV4@@fWv3LQkbhYwIgsK6uIuspKhGxiaD82Ss9B2VkO/6uAujH4NgLNF25HI6ZRlKvht439ELmycGh/dDdN8WegkK2IVcjLK0puEa/XBKuOb5eWC4WdFk/S0bY/Ug5ws6UqFaifQfD4@LLzZeFl0@eHz4/3Jcip2vv1hwcEWc@Vdh7@6tfA/0/mslGGTutRCaVbFksr6pWFW1Lx8OBNlkJZH1Hyyvpd1XOvVXyyOvg8@EXfzM72SqAXQfltQQlmEvo1aq2obN4ZPjhyz/AUyEu9z7fecyinjFlf/@nP9I3//5P/xUtW4pelT0au92MQEg0avnNyOXl8PLyCh7ul4vUIxyp7GYczHyoX4tUU5qesW27zEopw9jYTGT1@3Y5JcJqm1o84ikRMaGxmYt474SXni6Alz/jQE5yHksgsndk5XTt/hbyhBbsiGLB35bpFYEpCk9evWMMLK1qu9u1dDKlUqz0XmFb75Ut9h5H8N8ra@xVpYqTxBruo/IHuDdwuwhOBEWridRGlOk58KtdlesJRkPk0Kd7aZob9uk1jj5dw9Xo804bNvyZGx79YSTfwQOrbzM3XntybCOeSrXb4gyhLZPlqsAKGynA7DT@4Rd/Q9fzf/@nv/qu8a7xhQ59uGIxr@mRn2k/@xkEWLGX3@@A0UwAbrpHQ9BxY0su4oaeqBTB29k7jIf3u3HYcUPtwera0ANHm3SOGg@VUoMfENWOUbAN3OqbJP2Zjm@JlyUp0DNJP3a7rSTBYBt4SQLUUulS@gp6QbPKKiA4pa/MQIHDABpSp9Xw@mN3SBsEYhRPqyfZPYgCKXwFz95aoy3KQvoqILBSGzejcpQ9ohppR2xgeh6e5AXtifQViCIOtMO7nw3cTY8hLRvEvYpBCE/yaNcg7Tqk3ecRGuQao9zzAEnGseORbNChpa@AWkBUsEBbYNYWBCiDiPkKEADyEBOArTrbYpk4u7QSifLsmLArXA@NR5oZ/k5eCaMhtDbuHPcjlzEcOIHujlcoIV@IEgZFLeToA@Ew@NRtBbR/jE42VL9oq/2dQQEsOtYmRllj9@7NsKpUrHacUY4Q/pk1xHEmKgd7Ma4AzO85fdIuyUmGB7CVfdeA7YDiCUIXuE7hJ6@VQ1GZjNYrSYL/OzMtcuS1oiKPMmZAlBevFS0gGURGsvMybLGtCtP0zTgLkG8B7i1Cig79CrqDp5NPVP0L3/MKMPxZxD@gHATRSXjsTvDt9a3cDBrAMZ4OjQf6cGEgtmDzI3tQoB2M/NhBLMiK1afQHcuFrgpNKPvnf8UyWhyjzc5LIzxohbOeZbjQOBfHD8XC0Ay@Bp50JdJZo9M6Wg4UqDd0bDoai47xwFXcwBEgo8QJQxztsX2BtwmIsqHIYYw8Ol0IOR8xpqO@6BpGiosztk0X@rM@bZLM7KqsNWgzvchixGh0EpIdgItTJEK4CXov0rjZNweA0rFp0h4br5RKdUE/GjfpOKgnFvBVb9@CVsX2UuLGy9SFdWalTvA0ZMXp4FYcvrk@gioVVj8@OSyOXuo7zhnrW2cmH5KNzR1N4DHQ/EF9TQJlZz8gbAkXJuiZJEuDd5KHgt8mfDa5sZAMxV2LTeM3vxltLdbAEn1HjYzl4m2W54Ydoi897yTR2fWmnn@4CR3RAXY1ELmmONagEsUNy8F5HZI4pqVCJ4SoONQ/jEHX0z/eBI2glZvnDLutErYxIDRb/kEBWIsht1@hBoDqHtQsPOls5JbweAvAxG3HWlD1hIC32Scso0sYkJ89I86JARhY9JV56OAHUTEf3qgNBaPyrWcgV6B2DtrghxurBfthfJ@70Uyn0M3Ym60JcNjoUFoVxquFb8mFLFg7kJ8p62vgmQcMF2CyFpMTADYhx2UOOoh/PTrndolkSYndhJRkCEGQGqCQquBfd8tCx/5L4PHA8PjJmOJMtIuLC5UO5xu7lmp6eBS@h3f4poZdC7RjJzUyB0Nx6ZiFl00KuDOTwm/AwJudtyd0p3Lx3pR/JanjVcTSjVi040WxcTzHk967AzrUB0/T8Yih9i26JaIVE6tNOP/p9eSlz38l5D@lEL1CIIwhmElymmwlAViy2TpLdi7aZeFxThUSgEMpmr4jHojp@paB55usYScI4Yxox4Rvb/bPaNoSIMl8EHWWNM@hH3LqW4V9aE0gkm1esB3XNaYx8o9jaGTg2JTUHjaFZp98wAjNDLvkpzNak9q0Phd9EkSHRs3v/DAXT@yRLlcD5Ud1ov@E@0/Af8L9J7NE/WRrkzpXydDpCrODXI8HvfkhEczUD3PFj7Wc@RBk0LGZxkFgyOmc2xX8WhWK7dOb26AcKz5jAE8MgeBmLFV7eVo7rdueebFRT6S6wOwyEQJKHEDX6kTTi3ZgRur3z/tDx5tzsvF8P2iVBN7o1OoJbuC8gnkMCogYg9PLwiPZugMx3c8VApFhgIB6GHiiarAzilnxcnA0LHkC49TkGY05YjWBTJ20L@El3EBd4qTnhA0DqocAoXuQJUATfJhfc/jFJ750eOHi/e5@WIXuahjg0UDRehQoea2qcFlTpkIKYaUoPppAdlRXK9ez4vtDUdSueYWyeSXKP4z@2kej34F6sRh7YljeYJSlcFXBtWygQojqQlRl1UqoXAGD1IbRN11oufa4fipaa0hmI@V3M3g6mAXvAm9zjYUKvxXn5UO72GRbLgWsMK1UIIvTCq@WvF74JOUED6J5ItrUZwQRnwsQgJFeGM0U0SbhaJNKhQsONlkS7SKE5ISQnPAoPPRkCZJ1EQ16T8E14Fg8ddBOcSWdDPA03oyCGjSUGV7pirPPr/HYMpyvFGnOZA5xgeAhVLGRz1r1hanXQkiHhNY1AMiINwC0@R1qJem6wNOUwBbIKE5KX0Zxm2ADLiuAwUgEl/nRnrGAyagPDAq/nKB2AOqunKhJskYjvPiX5j856Tv6P@2mY3o@pDbvmE5e@/tHcawjZUMVNKR9aOksCmTsyTy3xZl4YZ0jgteN9hzQ6poXDostULbBPTUWUVPNvtNMDQxcRYI3K4nbhofTuN9/wNkRdn/ojIyRk82WeKfJIrZblD7vM1hd28ED2UNH@oKu13ZMz46OoFBbTte2PDPJ8OS1M1N0O0xxgrgU1pOF0fEkSYxG8m4sguZ8hapuo4F3PTYaMVwDFy8Fi25pSRyyZzQqYf8XTKH4IJ4E0MNhzGm@Nluj@O0w8fRpEe3Eap3FDofCMwqJ7DCQYS3Q/8G3BxoM85xZz5HOwUVVujmK0U0NPWfgdEHrG3uqhLGvgT@YwUaEjOGQcEkyA7u0pdAZ5FRLYq2kERdRP/voqOwzPWbEg/j6PIA5YiSZe53GSFl3QXKNpcnxaH56xx@P73EY3@PV@FIv/DrOvGte4Z4fl3QmNoMAAWdoZG5HA7MOcqt9A505VAJn1Kt4hDuj2KZVWm3EdAeC7ojgagf4IxnYPLAFiH@@jP6rC9CPvnfX4jPwAtzjKcibAS4ejNENAp4/zRmD4AfxuBRZkFzA2g/vmBaExeuL9lGFADWWBJeNR3hCxRxCt9sLDpb3Ad/C87gw6gbf02qpCvdcgJN7nmRn@vIiethom31jarZjImQyBNfP8RF02Ehe3S3jKOhI6Dm8rxeDtise@EIzjkTngUpLWMZInsfjy9mKB7EC7qGRcsLwYDn90P@GaMYhvgofrYZ@QDQaweHYcwuHP4fT4ZSfEt3nV58IOcrbH16SuFP/doIAHcRROMlZsvFV4vMoFmTpDi1CEFadzzIe4upDxJNkbpbhx5Ho9pxC4YYiVfxSluZvPFhc4taqEg9xhc@TfArpbix5G9PdmedCrMaBzUTY7sc1ITcg48qMVisWhshdVpaYY9@QCehG43T2klalsUCgBjFJ0o0s6m6TfhGXsGd8AF8ccPocvgiwa44anKH8vOGYlriRhZHPwBiGtBbhAko6QAlRkZNcoBEKJflmCH55FaTZWppm60aarbk0gxown2QokNSaS1KUAhbPqiLom53REumMXth3hs8qsQ2P7RgujlZcRq1oyUqy6Hm0BAI5akZLezEQytF2tPSQDF60dEyGs2jpMzDM6lb0XbTkVwsM4IKVDPfRXYhwtLeipd1Y/EoaGWem56erRktBmUKYbW4ligApMN@gNeIUm@2IbI5cExo2UiqTDDnGS2L3icZhkvRLwz@/w4TuQkBPHOPcoMAswbS5RiPUYvB0oNnwz9peUJNLojXfO9ynlU1BEEwmAX28cBwCD2p4JDovjDhi6EszGvAFBFFulhZjxEIt2R3REakDh1Ihz6dP1FNJH2jHyL8GgeuzROjiGhHfL695ELwA74YnRl6G5w10/OQII5yTjS9AC4n6KroiU1jW87iI0g@XEI11zwfCG6T9ILyUCGxIpoMOR5NzmNjQGc4zCfniWncrHIcG5XilRO69Fo2kgqiZS7zJWeQMBUO48sdXZScUD1GbE0HoWUvXeS0L2gWSxeg1k3UhTZVXPkAhJHOghputM7oU6KEwUjgubpLUVixrhvy4PEmSXPNiEiKreOTQ2Bjx1IPO6x4eRPRx3Vc/5gTHWmIIIBQzSIXLV@cj9HeH6@@@Qu0T4VoCixTrxU3pTfV6ZSt7DfP@LNmbBYieSfYwvlA5ClKYkRx6ByHNfBWv3VDxcckHV/J5ogH0a9q@T7agT3AL3a73LTgs1BLc83nHMx0cz/TlhLqpkfTPVV9pUTElAYdnPMB0lrXVuPKMLypi9KHxbaP/0QXszhdwuPAQHmXAvUZyXsvdsU2rXGZ1G8Q2d0GRqpUYF@Q0XRoU88wRxD1N3QbTtuBw2Dh6ePj08deh0d3c3IyLNno6ww9rLY61Bu04h0zLpIP2YEG3RU/iPR842Y3D8XRb@9qpLd@QJVxYgzJgQCo@@4k6HheyLCTPr9VdiMfDhigqYJ3NqoExJ5VQ1TGwybYEXUdAEHMU2zAEEF@9BXonqbcWpxstGg28obvRoOar0cDFS42GaMWwaPwZ8fjPImupsefSrYX8OpYLSaLjBNjDQ/bi0c4JO3m0x/af737Gvn74nL3YeXqC28SfPX/w@GCXwW/v6fEek@YWSuLVVdihBLo@NFsm3jCI57VlGUHedYZTLndiu3HufmwM2COnZeI01ZZnDO73uEW1zVGVx9qD7ugUxzAtup5sYI1wvQXdrQXdWFRu2rQ/D1f1MwjbhD7tAPu8A6dtdSwIK2Hfd2iZnr@li/UtKEGQt/7@3CRXkvAaLVo6RBfe4QqsC4huQHicuwEwBl9/RZegWx6PYLZVJggXPB9NwZO9oyfHDA8e2D18@vDg5ODw6THbPzwC67OvHzz9FOh5cHxydPDgOXpRwCeHDw/2D3Z3yIEjkFYZHgXweuyNVqKgYnCiSusMZ77prvvANj/qjRo8uzBop6LHomMbpY9l9K23ZjtalsYeqi@4O5KmClhsfefo08@hzWfmG5zh9KeCaf2B/Nyj69zW02yLUoPKUoX6VhbVFZo9RYvTfMRgyvB2B7NMRwTEyJxkPnBaxNO2TCbv4hoVHPvmJwlQXfZBQ0JrABtB@QtWKoxuZYlGk1sEsgqptfoOntbIU@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@f8U97RbbexI/qafQrRJ6IZ22yaBEIxJDJjEswQyGJKbY4ivsdum5xqb6zZg38Cc2f2xL7D7fx9hX2XeYX7tU8zWh6RWtw3hbvacm3OCu1tSqVQqlaRSVQlHuQIG@8CLEPZ1bxtFncbmxtPf0Vsm/Z0@3t2VuFQWJZO8OjW6cGLp5om6qtKjMmdCmoAYshOQBVnvqC8ewdTy@i16yGAvFIEifZQjuG9PXWUkRYhq3fl1BySLvFFSdreG74otsqiIL9hFHxezP3Jfne3S8pabiw1KhEFOR4loT0EuuK5hlkLz1RS43cfBgfx@Orj1R7Hj6eF3Qdt9FNrvwi27/DAsnpYMWE8H@9dHwPLk9n8CC233HgbMk@Q0NM3pmjm9hYy2pn28xp@n@o7GHoDBuRc1KBqoUdt1n46oVWxkhwu4Jph4QVQ73q0cHQmb9ydQFuQebhnaUgwi7HnxMba2Dfsk7Hy9aNKbZb14Ul8SFm3q32ODeSbxHhAVcg3iSXpoYRFfJd0Jxyz15MxCSwiyvieBqCiXxO6bkkFRXQK@hz0gIBt3mtFAa2YzMzz5hJFpBC7p5vHa2LThJwtrnrvxnsbhxARk2gQ1u@hZMrv/PvP6eEPVwwssjMCDDW7DShrmG9gn1KDiK8jo@8kefKRbVJeikT0vsDOKdmj4lU@usH@coYiReBHOa2FDrMvFsUSN18cLaplDBok4DTTR0lMmskUzJCgRT182zQ5140nPSU5BsMjEm/vemlwBxc/ui/oueSeeJ0t6QW6OtQXCpq6wPEPtrIRdfDjTM7SFXkuLh3RVIG0frSr7/1MVzxKJmhTNZzZGJQLktdXVF9@DnW6FKp79Udg8h6Tl5@jyCvb3MchoEpF6Hzi3euCp9JgBHiEdm9arAZMqCEudGXNKou00GZn4AS6sFwJkMCg5XoaYrtUV4xRus6HzjGRCpyxTbTCGsG4oj5op6t8/Xh0K5O/WN//76@PBhpnQdPAerfI/DIZREHvlGfFUjE/oyZr8FgyHfcrG/kyXCMUhN6ZHne3I244NXrlVmEjnbWZLOtI7ic1uPaVroEpIvejj/aeo3Sum1XvZQtFs6l51vyKWKBJhJ6GLtIe2a8ie@bD/GAIkg0kvgdMH@fA9izbgP@DgKZBAJvLmc4g27ndxI4rAqrlON8VIs1ApWwvp3u9ErWYfg3t49rNI2N5zKEha2MrhnjtLs54vJsoDctFV34FSnp31bSoK31Chi5CSILg38bsxYaGnhrKUfOTW@mausJ5fe21R6/reyLusvz7zllolW8Dk2@xfRtfD2/Yv3cHFTUf0xNVfzsetyW@/CrH6UrzAi@yec8TYwlopR1E4X8HfdfE6T5wrEXxD0W9PbSF8vilPiEUR78OL84JviaNN8wZ6SKS4VCxdKi5EF7tR6bK@dlbql/LFy3r/rIhOfqPl0mi5sOzgh@cwi4KM4ZP5@ugM51RT6xr0bwReoEoX3UnXEEGuIfDlQ3MYDvbLB@8S2jhcAKAKTNp6k0Kd7z6dQ2s29D3x@8GtI9VknkCOtXCBZM2RV1ABvdtJn4zqmHYImEGveLCajcb0d@Jac3n/@mo0oBQVGxBZS9yFd9accmPKk0YBstRDFUGQrnyPxnEeBw@G@OuEraizBV6uFdB30jVA1LEkiUP71LbRpxARlb5c9TMr8oNm6wKRwMt@76iY2Nykq3@B1SKftHhoytEcksNE/gwf8QAEfq7otAGroJV7RG4fFjQf3wv4wF9IRzUiPxkykLdopYgpaP4tvpF/E5XfBAIw4ed4zeVLFadcecFCkn0HSbmAEcaSG388ZkC3Su6UOWwswub6SjFwshQnGmG1kkzwfe4Wycm0gn@yBdkCvU01Q@d3OTuRhM6p5VuEtKQupaQt/OnFxRyjWFYVU5kNUsx9lxqo6YLt0YcAhtVE7AS9HiDNtJiLyYGP5N8r61/W9Ud1rPNMI8/p2an0bCLd53RGKs7lwwQfZ9owM9mZb3G@e2HH2bypukqCFi8@9HTLhyVJnLf4WN7IHw0aYZx5S3clc6VO2EwkZI2UrzN6n1PmE2U0g@v0OqdL/l6RPa@xTOR9m6wffy3ZQQEZz0pbkxSX@v2w98aS98TKFGQzG6gpBBfH/ia240EpfTClOIEVHOr5adhulWIoywUlcWjM2Fubb21fLjLeOGk02ItxamDNGCMGlajOZSLcmBwWoR5KnjdAEExkNKFG7pYqPJGFJwZYzDWvqmUvyKkBDk1LD/ES@kXe4R812JPIqXyZ2YlzjPmYG8/ezUkCkdCdt2eTKSlN0F2EP8pGPTKLxHVP0hBnC4kDQwus6wzYB7uDavB5LSdMQaEkxRTddYqkdJyhoNj3oS7ExHvrn7kl610T1thXvWAsyrjNaJIXlpVwcB8F0SjCKE8UlSa6vrrq4akjLfhuyYVaxgxZWcXjlhiiMbP7VhUtezi/h0/SIR0K@eIQId@igUicEF13u@hMhh6wg1sUrahxCUe@Ve5PWKEBY@bFCruZB@I64lNT2O13TSS453j0IKWjq2Yr8C1Yo0Ww@rG4qZ1Q3tNI@nT0G8E4YjClbVjWn6/D1i877/A891Uh/6JgkOxGHgfn/RcvYwcrIJJKWMnDMna18NKyjLPhFp8NZxGgJ/Zxov8EvBncBP1@YJVhxqCMESxao2B4E7R9yzoK9CEwwkVWxpNJ9MMeXA9brNyBRVcTmBG9hCOPj8OAw/AX52c@Lm7RWZln4aFVfNoMXX0TtpGAyuOkM8DTYTqwwDABTA8sdBmMgChLrkiiRGfPEhdau1yiIgqogXFOjLMJTYb@YBS2oGdIk2X1ABQfg8SV9dspTKC@Vq@JzsH@LATQPSamgEJAHSU9hoMlD81/Fw5CNkydsTdVz@RA@g1orMBwD4YhSN@YwNQrVMzAHTr4@H21JmqHe8efy0cVAc8fjw4/VXcru2L7C51x40E5hb8V7w/3Qbro03Q@NT@ED3a5BiVtSrDKB19E5aePR5VaTRweieqHj/tVgAbgj8oHx9VKzRPVg539k106fQcI4uDwWOxXP1SPIdvxoUe1qmJWXE4c7okPlaOd9/Ba3q7uV4@/UI171eMDrAxP9cviY/nouLpzsl8@Eh9Pjj4e1ioCG2btVms7@@Xqh8quD/VDnaLyqXJwLGrvy/v7qYYefj6oHAkyEjBauV0BLMvbsIXFmqidu9Wjys4xNih@2gHiAYL7nqh9rOxU8aHyUwWaUz764kmgtcqfTyATJIrd8ofyO2ic5XyHKtAvOydHFQyFhJSonWzXjqvHJ8cV8e7wcJdoXascfaruVGpFYe0f1ohgJ7WKJ/AuO6oaYAC1IB2et09qVaJb9eAY5oyTj2jv4EInfwbCAJZlKLpLBEYzCGwtEOnw6AtCRTpQB3ji8/sKfD9CmhK1ykgFtKjYOTazQYVAxGOzmeKg8m6/@q5ysFPB5EME87laq7jQYdUaZqiiQcYXYB2o9IRajf0EePEjMKulONej7hTVPVHe/VRFzGVu4IBaVXILkW3nvaS5j3FxDSVKOECdQfPSVKx0pj/dBBhmclojM1tHoyMm7RzuVmBGlnGr7DjhBGad9VQoJTMNZhqdCK@JkDXt4Py62wj7nQH6mOpirPi4jLoeXg/j4uUZp9Yjl3NI/QoVyGQajU/lBmx0a42G6z2lZAKN75WQavDHcrmyjRj3H3feqPjZ2GC6byYItfVcHnSSoR4eQGBOpv5zNn1rXgauyOXagSyGzvsIWKmOIj42ucCjFBCN5OyIN37EVZJmgt5DyQ5U0FHg/VYD9aRoGUmZBhH86d/FLzw5GB9AOrO6K5fDTSyhEf4WqGq4EgqJQH9kRIKwQ1X6URD80nXyZnW45/e7g0HbcV1VhvKOYB/YddzvFD8Puqni2XR5QpaOnWW4/Ujtu2kJo8@fJcmE7Bd/SC1z8E9jRD@uwoZjPqDWlKoiZbVUWjrPuThaJHlChrZA9wrqZFzzfSj/VP2Mu7n8ysti6vt7/Z3HFtoLYjhamPDqVO6Mft6fcQYYYBSLA0gSyggZuZxRRtmb6My3kPECM92GbbT8gbn6IqB5HUgCC9nrZs@sE2fjYTg2sQc5/O6o/GH7ZG8PRCdi@3J99dVa0dJht37y@PcL1kMxYynq2BXM47BOoyRjlOzAwodGihFVO2Z/YuBcDjNi2HTVafQR4zxou42kJRMKMmxuhNff9NFEzw6QDragABzzluLXmSNTMoCTaKqLrblsjmmJ34S1EvGANGbpTajXxvgHYevhr4a4bpBkIMliFEUXOBd2FyT37D1lKkqbGwrcg1l8W/Exh3HTNCBVF9nPonctvUneNnoxYlNGHK/U7VQSkJhPYyGUXUWfR/ZHijMiFcAUPQy@/CT5DR6/yAB3FO6uGY3KoxqQcU@XRD11rIyWja5LyGd4kw0GVVM1bQrU8rsSKRp7Up2sA4MYo4FQwatK0MY3Cbio44ikqyQL2LeLrvjGnIrBOxBOUXKsfAfOndUcCaWo4ofIdxWVQjAsHeSEqXar67BUli86joUiZ4JMP0QPgv8H0mQG/E3YcQL0mFpGEMAnUZKgMq1g@0pECW/VQYNxuhFT0/z0JQZzb3bMhW6YPL0Zs38NkED2zkR9@EJhDzvODAIgk6Niwxy/2iTtoglbp7e2K4vjOUm/dXnlCDlXqKliCm527cyjZZenzlbwxRUu65qMCvehqHjLG7dzGvWwZUpt5cWzyGZwror/kVsiBYge8MSlF2y1muasvBxlSg7IUEvGhNPWEZNgWXr/4KndkjBCZCZkvzz5UoQC0FuIz3Q76T6PgWDz3GTERZqJxTFFwcPI4LhNxslHhqw7J0PMXoBwnrVJGYJXfoxucYLoMXQK1RdDE84zMhTBSmKrwzjOIIpb1wfS0rR6q7EnzSRyqMb@pM8h6QPWaqkcPgf4kBia7vK@@NCcAMq9pzWbWSy3VBt4aLuIlbFaQpbH601ag8EQlo5NbDfg6IUT1xefpdIh6EfXQxm/EOazcCg1EmrRD9Xgsol37zTNcDR4Qi0KR@it0PaJP6hJlwFaiHJ4knF2TTjAvIpHt5TSMRwvF4SzGadsAk0oLCkRcVOsibs7zsUElSFDA6JgGOnNBdlsUj147qCH3@1g@AvO/bgE6reDto5MaoAkXSB3UrVPMR5bI2761SAijQZ0BWpANCUKrEjThqowR7@S7CTtmuw4OibGLqWW/P56NJMqaymoKGZcWTsw31oWOhOptCJDg@pgoYWVVUJl1obr/sHNGEULTR5bC/u0r0XKBi8iSs/U0hGfWG7qpy/4JJX8pWcRjh74gmfccgmKCOOaFc9Vp@Uc4Yc2BZ/DYNg2daKwkmk3r1D9RlufQZ94UakOZdi/VnMUBRPYAbRy4ThHMBrOnwYX/cbOoNfshoOwCfs0DOg@ZomHjxN6xA7rDge3Ed3cQwltI1N7Ej9zfBkOw4bv@lyyaITmikbBlWOaKYyGk/IFh4kgzTkaAcbXVhJ/X6VjpOkyL1fjQlbS/5Ts8Qpu8cGyLwqzCvOJPgKQAm4rZUHBPqQjckwynE@LUxnOH8tg4HgusqLpPmCxl8D4NZCIjmESGCtkpswSzEbgzuxBjOvtsdemGIRDDLQU7AZ4@Uzk0GeviTcBgxR5g5YCG6KwnjeK8inKGOMQ4sPkYXKvvPqDsQcEfgD9wotZ3DKLEUjEdVS0pYj3KzLKKOBC5oEhyWiSxCDFwi7MQr0E0MY4DTWZPHmIGmT5A4siGWZviitxRDqw8cEL5pwGiJzGxMVJZVEsuhS3A5cg5ZGTf5hhg@/Zz9Lgx0Nc1pyhYNqRkB0D6YdI1QIq4UWqKfNaE2WOqfz9EbOy8tReSxGwNMvkzLjz17HVyoU8UEKeX/FYazAEYWynqCdNPRaj0eBq8YnUe1B2zIzMNovWLdf9riEwM1sJJsulNpG2NMHHSdFK45NimiTFyNIMeAi3r/Ss2TxNxHGpgeOt1Jh8hw4P0Sy2m9KTiu7vNo99nBRv0KJXTTR6SBHuGKS0qL/XG9DwxsMSRMLk7VWDJEYDRUZjwo8GqBSZNJWeTiHiPol7ih5toBzW2wbamf3zIFHTRnIq5KlKSgS5RHpi4HZ02gS5dNVB4wsME8crXC2k9IJz7E3oKK@QPccgw5jAAHFVHGRjPRRrcOPOSvER3Q7QcRpoLVRASQRPW6aFgw76rwlGUfmlckdaPDQm2cJZkSGNNSTYVVCuxyApf3N4rTfGBGWKFDDEZ5BCt2hKNl08vVU/2hbIBxC4NCVLS9@8h41xxTJgA3/MpMYY18BxVbJkYkQlB0KDRAOMBdildHsBb1dx9RcOmePRukEOI9hA8GcHf5ZlCQznvZbX1MYi4/YEs7iS3DzaXJHd4iIxQ/E7kl8ORV7q0sYVAASMMZQvFQAChjUl7PFQgELvmJyXQFT2ERQsFXBYwkeKihrbec5IR6LKDC9XjRz5WTlemzCyM4HAwmJ2nhgRWLPMzhJDgYluJi5Gjlez2xPngAWx4n2mOHSF7JUkDXXPMQHp6uO8G0uUekF4ecnBlPhy1U0kav6m1Nd5IzWfTgX6aAzr2UI6dT2fSE1Uu7KSLJooCfRwzVoTiUAK10RYS4Uf@0euKWbIc20TamwyEqsMaZ@NV1PDLhP2bf5fIrFJTtlqjaHgmZ7havvV4CtWEkHZHw/ALhbpyABjt/9wa5VlqsJE3hVAcemUs4vDG0Jasdo41WOzcKerIu3pAAVqTzvoiE/He3uJsK/nE2VodBkMV/P5PDLxuRn8XtlWoyopHOSSuXOd614vd3X7p@Gn8xzJ/iCgKwE21A46gC6BQRH5g2GXb4ZAHCAr5s5KR1bc6193OuYVDHhCiZ0H3cY5ZTQEQRNQqI1ePh2TAohAygn2Z2wgtu9noUffbZMXmhKKOoaC0mgSfGOr0zMgD37ooH22PqkiYCiYlTUTzFtuaesbziB4swl1FoUvdr/F5sn2@6DXG3jiM979i5EC5u7TBfb2zAJ5zoInjOTdex1RPFpPBDdhz/ArxiwmryM4NTGpeyZUXHiMjX8UdCvjK8euf7VhWoEmL2MzlzE@tSfsru3KYPFPAMt8CGg/Kfdl88ppEZ3SmWGqlyM4fgKMXhS8mXufRBaXdGKSZt/PjUSdja5PwRqg6S6tBVQse@peaskD2TVx7dNxoYM0zDMMiRPGXHlaCXQ1@@PE4s2o03maVKRrALhjf5dE5JtQfkwg0hkAjUA5/ICeGEX7X7IwrPdSAUV4gYOXdUzLHSzQwAKW9axV@vXWKZfLYuFqeVmUy9vwkM2K8nZZ7OKH7W2xC@/b@P68tLK6WmSZu@t@g4/b6uO92AYYpOFcbl0Md@EV0kroN4bW2tjFC7nSgldcaJQ2t4pRrl7eRrd@ePrHv/77P/7tP3Jl@fJf@LJNL/WvOpPv@7mF1reF5/dFfK/vni0unNcXrs4Wu0Xksn9S1PBBdZRtxuaj/vDcyvAsYHwlO1K1z6boM7KoUPf7XTaHv4B02RCZVpTLyK8R3xxFMjbTCozvAfpRnsMWXl06kN7KAxIZADpBdTz0TitAAzyYb4CSgAvagXJ5PltRinsMB6Mz6FOVjIzEQ2vWmwB9WuJICuiLCzNWNuxHQR814De05uXmWVYTfsNRQ/Jv7uuHqLs9GIulU0cs5cWSJ5Zsm34Ka6/hq7uQC9E7l7PBdsC2PUiJjxbQzFBEIS30aP9Ad@2kyG1ZC3RlD0JSYSooM3vBeXr3R84yfOFa1LXm8PpMwSoSOmTCIplvC/176JZvkOPeTrja0EKhIXcxVJlxoqL7F5dAzYgNAeKaL5kgGwOoEk/6yCMZn3Lqi@xri24TIsBI1qN3ezTu8QPMRQt9afOc2EvhNUdkPs9fcW4ssjM0oY0pXH@MAB2o8HYyT56Ei5lFi628jVZSM9kL22yfZD62dZgEI2WbzoX@KgwmYGtuk3ALfenXIg25@XhF2KE@XjGqstO238Iyilxe90bhlXRXoNpxQH3Ttd3zSMIeJUAMh2P2b0yPMFIUqEhRqW7hy7Imoj3ApvNI6EvXdOhg1@eTI4MIua8OjO271Nh2c@QlotiBeYCQ0qZ8nWbYi2TUlSERu9scnuPtgM0OXag24nMz0ufhhakpjAcdjbRPkMnkPB7P0JTM1bDZvWx6InMwOB42J1WYtmDlM2r5LrQQQzAhEjj4ZNWzmqcQ5hbJLiGK6KaQ5RBeXtCbyOvRuG9t7XOCXaqGggy7goMgwU5EyeAu0VcpOsZc/Ts6wUR5Snjr00gpYknyoqWRhGSbbjM0zKaGjqVqMMeOHji2xajqkal4QRa6xon2kg5@QZL3MEaArNuWXoDSFWHtNdaPs1M36DcTk9NVz1KO/rmi4HkRxzNdRcnWSJa6BLUQ33iHWME68msyCgTPTSqckTXnOHOnkbzOLWPOIxTkW9vi55oi1BfQ0QVm5BkiTvohC8vUDBXfgeGLKln@A4ROr9kF/Ca3zQmy4mnGeTOfc@tfT/tnS85p/@70N5cwkSJZzbJZkZGH2UpiybECM2POS7wqq7RIhRo87ScznPYF@7AYJABEck79a@7sLgcInWbwdvnTDBMk0WWISe7x@nIIPjeFZiaJRS5jzblLrup8503BFTC30i/2IX9w@RewUJtKUtPDPmfYAVDkp/vrNbucRLn1lfzLlcJL2Al1g3F2GFzjfJuNrs@DMSwlItzOwtRz@luCGxKEuB9HzSJ8HEM7@VoT9j2JpJOSFKFymFM9lmYrKOMzT0B@oDKFS0UXF1fnaeLhI274PQEsp/JSLCg2HTS4z8H5MxpcYj3NCOVa2juEORKtDNhGhFSoWYSsLl95iENdNVwWyc/JFzsYu5WAQPfmMsZs0R/0s3Kx5vqLRVxEo9dMbz2/nk@P0akhmhihC3IxtTgvCltvXv39Pw9/zYwyWyu5z0P4HWV@zaytZ/gRHuDthXq7yWxlNjHb2n1mkoM9MDy@@vt/Q/mtPwEcTJlswp@tVQVrbZLZypaoyF1maw0eCisrUO///O1v0IYF3rHhXawLDU8QYkVFkZ1mn3gX0kUVW8nb0sVYrJBjFsJgC0PYm8MLGkaNV9bzpKbLSKuKm0BGvlL2KHKKJ8OsEZkKsSZD2VPAyogLlLCCLINUJhQdYdhuKLMNZN4YTfHzM38tgh3Az9KcQ1epTTeeRWgytMDbIuhAh2uE/Tw/bOXf2Nq8Y8NWNiVFtYTErZ2Utesviv8L)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/eighf)

There were some compilation errors of [Maze v3 interpreter](https://github.com/olls/maze-interpreter-v3) on Ubuntu 20.04,
the fixed version is [here](https://github.com/stasoid/maze-interpreter-v3). Compilation:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev libglew-dev libfreetype6-dev
make no-gui
```

Maze code is based on [hello world](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Maze#Hello_World):

```
#^^aa>>.............................................()
#aa->=323
```

Initial car direction must be [down](https://github.com/olls/maze-interpreter-v3/blob/master/cars.cpp#L10), but here it moves right for some reason.
`()` is pushed away for Prelude, filler must not have two consecutive spaces. `#`s are for Flaks.

Answer (score 2):

## 335. [OS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2) [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), 15000 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]x PPX~_~)"xvy"\(   #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #          z      2222222222222222222222222                "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[ aatxy \#184  O@  <!-- &rem  (22)Siii/ \psddpsdoh ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55 k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//               18&1&  nthteo nthieo nthneo an-;et R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWRp&if -%*==- (echo 330&exit)else echo 335&exit
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L    1  >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 101 1 1 \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1ta@.7.8.2<uaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]'4o'6o@<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMn n n M n M M M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
*/
#1""/*
333
quit



































































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata#8;&&1Pr"93"s>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[s]pogr61!\0k:4op>astdequ+4[]!!tfc;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ/a> 892g=1\'  
 
*/
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD40dHw/IgjULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt1S36pStaS6dftSLBZIgiSuQIAFkBJZKlV09@z2um3PrKen7Wi3Pb7tnvFsez0R453YWbd37JkIez9OOOaTf0D5sbHh2HD/g97MPAAISiRV5UfExsZCInBwHnny5MmTJ/O80Na9wc9@FsOLPXWsWd9yxmxseGPWdc1zw5XZvRm7q5teXssKAsbadfuToWGPvYoQYypj3lh3x8zS7f5E7xssBr4am7/3TGtsuGnmGQZrG5ZzAeFZxmzjgh3YHbMLkNjYOTNs87XhQliOsfuG9Wb4Zsw6znCo212PjVzTHlNonrGnOrz0Jp0zpre9sat3xqZjQ1CBsWe2pQ/bXZ1R9JFr8ERFBqA6Z5RmMaTE2GPH9QzIwekYnuegZxk8ddd0Hu0@@fhafDXDPtYBqZFlTK9lr6rsuWm43espNPbpyYMH132z7BPJsdmDmyipObY7GTsH4@vw82y3b9g60@SyrF0PLAAxx4ZVypQyC0EQ9sB0oTZ1v9Yq85qxJ8O24QLx/Sq8MMcDGRKcOJzgzLGtGTOmAAxw7EE0Y8xMrC2Wz2QwJvwfGx3H7s7Bg5cBcACuMRyNZ0xituPzAAQ5LvNGeseQuoZlDs2x0WWWCdg5PR8bj0GFszNjduG4UPESZ0VCxBsZHbNnYhK/BJ6AzHbfaE/6zJmMRxNAz2Nd09PbFkRrz1jX6OkTa5xmbQgD4pH/xcCwfZRMu4/leD73QQg2NAGO/aYKtDEtiwE6Z4gOZu2xbQy4QH@M2jYIS6OLoPbn5AJIuuUFpV/MeCEbTPfUdfquPgRG7RpEg08PnjKv47jwBj@My1vBOjAdfcy2t1l8/8n9OKuHZJTdthCStMYuGWOxIJCd69bE8NhQn0He9hgaF3Oo/oIUAkRn8Y14hcWzWaZlWC7HctDYSkzLZxg0iTI4oNVqWRV@BaaVWE4Fvs/H05hPz9X7pmVwKH3H6iGgInKslmca3DM5llVL8TSP0aF8iixbYoUiK@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@vTRyIIOAfwNIMREtwCZC50UCtI3orlyhCARpusMTABIWYFgNl2jQ7T3iw6psyDCF1GsMK1@J4tQ7kX6lSwbOSCVPUxjTyyrAv2l0WHZutI1zhX04X3PYp@DOAS9EXSoPoi2DsoA9caIRQjpjiZTP3cS1KznDBeLxmXTQVj0gYl9iHWhz6D2eiCWjKk@BJWFoV5gQ88/BI7hNYg14fGe64B1HTs@DqFcuNA/Q6HDkgBIi2gyNocGKHQOJMEazxHSKBkJs/YMWJmolZNJn@OYXCOULFwnFPfIRTx4Y4GesTvpINUwb9MmDoIexUPlxjX0LvcTxi47PdXh50LXN/JVWRkdGPEYUYtoWtBvGkB9X6noEETUdQzbA73Jk5mJCiZwft/pAbNRZw9KCySdw@4QEZAEoddU7sgCkRwZaHhmMZN1RiMG/qDpAHs@yJSgt3a@MNlrCLQGHrM6E9edsekIasIcQqxxx@n1gHtfG6MBgGDDLuvMOtA8oZKRe4SuQ5KoM1os5vxt04A4tgHF3nv6ddY3gOzQt/cAU2L5eQFGIyoCkUK3eb9v60ApLEJnNCOyAJgwRc9xZPTvOoZHzAJ6Udj0MTPP6FPTgHbWmwujIeoxwKWgW9jAuyB5/OaF8DFDYWlhMCufCz42bGg6HeBKaPRQfVinu6wHVkSky0c1Ue90jNHY5xOHxJlpR1SjwweoGpGv5AOTvYGweRe0ukWugagh50T0AP2MpCyaDKSx6ShrfVMFNAPbCJVhxiWLNbuRPcQ4v5a7@BLjLGDwUlyBw4iaBOqJJCQmYxQlKB3NzgBl4RilDekq0Nrcyc3ig180e3fIpF6YN2KjgtgRZCX0QjxWw5DgZ90EJI8shFVf8MCoCx63gNa94RLIToik1Y36yooug1C8DejQsZ0lUIGYIVyMshhCdUHMeIxSQ7dCZqTm4i3UEQrsuRWNHRn0oaOR40LL4EJnhiKNV1mEuxxu8STCviIJFvhi1wpdRhw7/PGYW28jCywqamLYUkEr1UFSgBDjtgTIPIfnGEGYWj3B8vG7INHPmQn6Uts2ULHV3RkHAsWD7hkymjHTdUEMnmMnwfugoDORiU@hT9C7XZSsSA5q99czl5Gj9yZtc3rdYOmgp/yFJ5zrLuuhreKC0gGNKBHvefFklfwpZSRIVJzRWKGk/C5CRIokQ5UnemD@QCfxAATN8czuJMSFJiammTgZ90piEhyYkOto7Kv6aHwduy/AD5lmeAbtmt6qrA/dtyTBXUI/wgQDFBkDdBf0DGiEoKuXy922zt6A9HCZNN2j1Khc0lOVc2Feht0N8/IJgbhEyyvzLDy3Qw4p0qthCTA6lZw6iQUCviclKKEIHori963oQdoeDyO9hntObBpoYAmuiiTZZajoQweQIGRMUD7Mjjlu@erKnTuB4rJRqwGzgTYFYrObjJoIwYiMDJIaIsukjfiZyGPneIxtI5GE8mLkK44NqE3AqbU6uxwPXGhx9H4lQCQgq2AjJweE9ev5iXk26V6vaBs9MZKIrQ6UJrMzFqsCdP68NdTWUTW@QFUwIeJIVWReTE@gbzAv@WKFin401/BQ/a35qERqOIEY@Ly6lEQ8qe83Z@i9WcfyVQLugsbOpVEb0D/zbf5QEKV9nSBotDdaKgeCzYHDYU93Tx7W/LbIA5W2aVcWPCyno1vkvYnRxSDto4N7R7tHX28tgWGZ7cp1D8XMlQrY1U6mUt@eKDlZq2xGYcwB32@th40JF@OIgh/MJGcaUZVmHehcpgE5D48@uU4S0ISQHJQDuPF3TaXhcUDpEtq6N7jWCbN@KgVZhkmCuEw6YAHM0IGoY7ge4PN08vo1Vt51pEa@P2JmTXQOIPBUDuwgnYyB1xSwIKjd4z0ipQUt1LRxJHXuisYM8PkYtebryJAqHWGZjw8f7B/VCOxA984My5IoiuKNQZfS3a4MPG9NuoawLA6IP3B1WEqeI476NOG6lMCdzgKB53XLVsAHAGjryA6TrGFQNG8AuO9dLxv5Sp2QA@idIFzXK6P6UOdDEY3ggV1cB03eZb0oBcw7q9BraY8Vhi52W5183ijmytFuqzPPsxsFOiSl2HQCvdGFoDNPQh95rkX6arWP/vGjG4h7pESCKSAFmHkWkykvzxLQepFMFveUPbDQHMuQn5PEE5mYVJR4MIQqdzwyPiPx96fmOJFJ8qeahLiQ@@7ugXY/iOwP99FIBhkNaItjz@T2cMqi4wGP2I7l9B22BWm4dhhkCGrTymLu9h37Rg3p6IlFjeEcCMhfHLjRR9DXmK/JcKRUUXOVz5/otncBUlotZJFIRCECpVB8@Qv9XAdyzct9fPD5PnQiaj6TCd0ZuoAEkTRELnR1Ir7kwSTISPbxWVrAcD7kRmsPAqTIhAQW2hd0YcLdefBST5KYsrI0/lKUvurcoPgXzuwaa4EPZy1wREh28OTpo4Mn@493Pzsda/n8wnsuUy4A4SC/NuhC8oDTDVvrFm@aWCwEF4O24WLzAikwAQMlGFifeC4IbhmjyByBFVzDZ5ISX3UGdtxLXi/MBYZKX9gdzkKPsfHxqH5CMLS7FhojLp@Aw/4c@WcwHo@8iqJAKx9M2jIYrcoXHcfS@wqlg47BshQVTZeDQxzX8JalAGS8mcFT8MEtUB1mNIKoW0MHjBea1EPRwBIcPI1aWWZ/ALYwzvwZblIOOZhKo3TBQgBbWQnLRgKY3oC2/jOoJ5Gz9ldUrcT5Ws1oOUUMoi00f4i70TPAdEpAbwWkSF57Zad3Tu@wGUhphHQdSIzJW/7kD/YFFgNFkkZN0c4PiEPSAsdLUVYQjV5NcDQXpJSSz@SKaiGvgFkGZhrorBKOuUlDfdwZSGNHAniS06NxgwgX9ryObvfkLd8RIAt630dQ1Gzjxemp3QQF/fQO4YZTao1Zs6E2k1V2M8mWHz9ZBe5dKB7ybuABvEtOYE16shXyrKvfFGddnVpXlynj4cjvc6QRe7wLitRrB@R114i2PUygRAOVrYW4CkZ@qywZELIwqYA3pJQCDQp6WmA9BfGSQOlF9RA4B@RWJAGbj2bwcvCJ7IgcQaMb@d504h6N@KNeg6Ol3giISIPNHZTSHo4PjqF3DDkfpTRULgppdmHEcRxd9/hoJSTypy@D9GCrhRBoVD4ckbbDaVtgAkpF5jlIDuArHDYdzEcZ0egHToMMCSccfAANwqbZgz7IGUjMC7LLC8JzIp/FIp3ZzoWN0NoGK0ltc8wH@52Ji9OCZjdaNoie1XgcgEaFi8h1mj9sGx0@ysoTUynACNTZ0Bg6OJQA2hWJAoOKoPO5R7QFPRyxhmaVkXD6BeBL7O4eSLGOwceLpCEaUcBS@yw@dpVd6XNFl14DN6/RrbDwu9GpcKr0k4AANBIZzoXTKIk/AkraiTOkSM9pvAUD7wXqrjCajQdQYuAwUa85I8O@bvNxizCRrNKMbTwOAt@0E5fxjY2NeCVej6fBtQOubXTtoCsFrh1ySeTCeDK6KEWaXBjaoBTo14xfNQLI02QTeWCKmsNrc5TQG5VKtpnWG6r/1PCZhKoAykNsCR8AJ56s1dCZTIr1C5yzAf09UvY95J3jjmuOfBJ8FRQC/u7TIEtEAPMetXnXqKJtup4iw5oLRqOBKmbCjZ82MqfN08vTbur0Kp7G1MmqXgP7EITXODGU@64zGYHi1shVJJBtyUa20qy2a/FMfCuRKEkWZKQnkx@Vkimd0zoRN4CnEqencSCpT51GZ@ASvGlaSyZDQgEePROsDMtKxOXLEuTfTjaTqTikTcbTIJZr8TjQpYNE8KjQOCLAmeiBOQVSQsOELi46p0ACkiansLl@bowGMzcaIRx1Ay0bR9Dn0/rQGEiKR6Xka54@qtAtWPqB3svjgXKLg3eoL41mXLoLHNNTZWGJSdDvnku9oTPWlU9lMJrkSHcZ34grkgQ9IYVwSFTsx6aHTVi3DWfiRUcalw6AYu7gezKYgLAM1t@kgavMkWB0Bg6Lb94F6Cyc78GuBKeuJD4BFgDodmT4oRBFrQQnS0C7oIUpJshFXLTCR2VUQoKLnmBsPl8YvZLD3KqUhmUwI7NvO64hAUkghUDLSGjRkVBn/tqUAxr5ujEv4YdSl4aGt2mARHxgOTrRlovryHzQaBhJD/Y5JDkyuoIF8qMH4lHmdeEaXWVLoFlaxx1ADwGlQUmshbU19AMUxxt15fEUkgoJ7HCjgdy6A6XzgnU1TSt08r1KEIZcAcQeQCWhVWqDiRsESSoEJv1K3ufDQoGN/uTw/j4fO6HOFrtXHEdrDZ3uBPRK3246Mux@mu0DP5m2MzSBDEH612fWkeOMuZUPL6tGZrjRbA4nlk5jPteHZdam6zhtx6KhoHVJ5/EnrqdbOh@ECkJ3P30Muv6zk@OaXIlEUvTz4dq8cRxyebacngfROUeabw2mhzzOmOJmXsR@K1jWhmLGDyhgwMRf1AZ1FPgX0T9oUjiH4vuX0H@IC9pAV/ZHEeg19PQjlikiLnLDtUG@56WauUL/lTZYGE@leFxxnGN7qWrkfz7u9Ra8s@R9JqFosubeOfLmi90WbMQoSnkeCVe@LcSJAipQnHAB3PV4vvAK1xoMDCuYQTwCxQRnyaBvt1B9AtsENXG@Cs0ARXqEkyEkoXGKjXVA1/RuDFtAmxpJPLYQ26B2An2YgpqLsKkwf4i7Si3FdvypSY9LTwdMexo92a7zyWw0nVxutSl88H2zBSC269VgTdKqaJhTPB5GI6iEG6SgYtL8/Y2ihqsxPBpTFyhJVfAUsBqmWkY6nRb3m4pHROgx8fR0@lFG@wyMD1w9tnlH6RtVzG4lteidj0N3BiA2WGq6SDKoh4ndc6yuxCe9oP4ZN5ewIvw1B@H6NRL44GO6wdI1E1ez@EsMQVxGVr3dgHut6uo3I0TWyYWAoDVcsjdn6fM3rAE92LnsjSxz3GRX8thpDbDw44lrX19Rx1VK19VnnuAvWamx3aOPP21kmhyCMNRxIqvEa2saLMgEPRj0Hlz3Ci5ceDM2x9Sx08ICE8uryoDUlOY8AH2AwTOosjAjv0SI@hvjzbwsPQMMz4SBmHuzYZoZySu5Z@njsWFz3uKziavJzad9/GxqlP2OP4dQYRmaaAFF08QwQLHKjk/u7x8dycChXiK@jxMyFWh2emcA@saqQgeUjBa@wj7qxtlHmCaJVrgATQqMiZafHpi3CswN5gTkjqKgb7gJ8EziXEoHvGn6ihJyhcsnEC6f6oyJRiGwhJGEMhGwylL8n9nccvLxrLA4SxElgdyJOxWgrZmUJ7b5Svag3yA1FKLEue1Ji21rmwkSX5tqkvjHNYc4FwwmE2mBUIZGg22AdKPYIqu9ZS8aGancTG2yZrPKZ/ghIer0tHjXXwiq@/Tk02EkIH2cD3yrrHdtOXCQA43cYiqOnwo8K/h8C8i6k/bsZisVNzUxGSIrvQYPHiheR3LJclWOYrDGiUQILYlaXNq0uHAqUqxnZGRfW2YOxQkQCMuD05AJXkq2UWNqMhlgxgE91100nSvsqeN5ZtuidbA9y@RLwsLOuuITxocUUCaaXRUbBtEN2zO0M6yM@eJnvqTYpwSFU0cDlhSWjDwSSXaJxCRSakhF9uYNeohsU2PEBiKuPeb0vQpsWpCPjxxA9pG/ljqqc5DQ8JenoOg4FcTAeFuc/8UQbhgo59d0XulcjKbjOqdpnzk0ixS6WhlZzaOeGaYenlk3U/ZMb0C3haghDjyutgo7b9ju0W1JBJpM8afpyYOG6X0NG6pTV47oQSP2S3JeXJqykG3b6E3sPs1poptJr26JKZVLFLnXbpurogIRcLVZ8FwSDWQltjxNzslq0HpwgAe6RZCf3CaaF/36qia2QHfopMaQyn/@1290gf43a2cA/RWOZ4aOFmgKWFNSb2Vl@UnxhW7LK5YPu08sUyfCkOs2kB3dhSLpVuhYDpqm9iUJ9I0hTlT4NQ68iTfQRdewGceczzMGz@WZLJuqs0Fud1bFvbbKi2dFk0pgLnaJCFznMg1KREKWV4Ix5RM7EcMdBe7tSAVLsRgxM6/3wWQ84XdQh2@tRHOEv3Vt04@Zyett1QCDVG@bxpoqd/WzSdeRRmf9UC0uLIk7Lz3NLEuglfiTzC10Li8@L6Br9qG7D56ros37V@WCHrdxhWdPvJHUJtu@y9@oIQzX5OBa/L4qiunveQodq6lmWnR7T070oQOj@GssFFzBKkWIZl4js6W3Z6gKDT6cy8L1CiBxap1UKpNdMWE9Gq1Oj/YppS@Xl6eeyh1Oj2UjDwpfJSvxsTkqsL9u9pZahe7KHOqWpHUjzpXCfNlyhxtRw5lSSmOc4zzR@dKam1MfO6TOxNLduWsNi8/xCCYnVo1z@93GU7PjgDowYmpRVrWg64h0GCQygwV384xwkTLdIosqzGVk7IIVip24FLqWiwCnM8aFqCt46j0EGl8AistsI0wiO6so1XEu8LdSfRiAJczvy3u010uxeg/hJFkdS4d@fGV3sDDkiEOatzDqhekZdFtO2LOliI471lL/xSYQDCZGBwdvY2vPtByPHdN9HYH6LlCB35czdJSWpm5LNMQeda@RQcHKiXmF6lbfsQqlvqLDbWWtT9weyn3/@b4SLpRQqnqLhArUH8dW/edKuX6muGe3VRBtIXNx1WzEuaaLXSam/Bmd1aUDwwCnA5eX7EGmRCllhQ8grsgYJ3Iu9Fnw/Dt0HatIG3Qdoxmp06DdYYJyCRxjl6vYf5fccutz676fULoBtnhbISKVe2YZ0FnR/UaVMi2jfmAKNZN5fxHVsybGxFhqaBy2vzBwN/IaI@P9kcr4xdj0x/9xygE3vISxXvuW4Xthjf00vq0VJjqY7MbtqsyiUBuB9j1C0/kpOJ6i42aKvj0ZLdTqgnVmH60n2WAUNGmnu4AdhnyoHCrdoikt6OeeQb@1FhO38HDZWS2XyWR8BSYyj7Pwss6SyoZpvzD5fSFj8pnnPI@Lc3duxLk8DyJLdGHjShGkrTLsKXK5rNimbYxneH9Padp2HOtDagqEatdEVQw0S1rAu67Gbqg7/tYUNh@68HDAo91bNWjBexvftgT6oNG8rtKjE03vVZsSTqUOcZpr8XX98E1k2uq2XHBXOI4J8SW91mpd0h8NUeWSXFzb6riG6rQNS@ePaSG3Dl5Zzq6Ftyg0/ClgnDLmE8XzCf7YNaE0mgGxzC5YKQNjaNDrGi1f734x8YLHykhTB3@rgqeG0VGm@0ZnVYSRCXLBxvvCzHREWRo7NthXY1w9iHaKhetTfd9VEjiYS1xK5IOh3jf4URfrJOV8wALX6HCzbu5cPnRR4etyOpBsPry8miWgUZ0ZMy94LgX4eNaBep0Mbx9uu9b4OzgG@h6tfdXC2JtdrD1wBvbAGPDV6OHbqsYB/DjmR5OsQx2w7g9wgdxotLBwPkpPy7Gs96EnikYuKB2ntxSnfdxSi/vBPgjuTG9DgP@4dfBOH3PZgY6VrWZgTKBf8pyxMzIkelsV1cKBHn5fJUODqe@/6wjSWjsfKBI8/67wb7Ut@7ozHo3o0RpZE49ulFSindC36U09vuCFllo6bl9@7Qzbsu8p@6thaMZ9uYhpm@POALeic842@k67MzBvQ7pt6GPbPFOCIR/@@l62K1LGZNJ99JYtE8jrzmTkl1o0/BgfB6sq3R894t1a6FijrywboaPN3tJIP@t4fDQUXayCA8KR1si3hFdoU33l1cQcz4FGVkiFw7t8WgIdq3D312Ss1Kxo58VcDPtrNVZyKSnpqJBLRgYUHnVVtour5yJNLJvlt1UIRUtJGEVWu3wIuf0VRTQ6aEbGbcF/gb8WlkIt7eTswaTv3RSYfLi@Cyoa3lYPW9AK6ciQNfRZuu0/VpFZsxTcOgnPFuhcE2PtnEp@7aQKxVMtSXdMeLTgAVU3WTmGZpkjj9@Z1Fs5FeevkAJb/Pp8IafNbLkx7VdM1@jxKRB03aYiDh2apAUdROrghD6OoKMw54oXF1y20wehLllsHjmIu0ptWbr4aHn1h32m9NkTo6/jCu5H5hiXgC7hCmLZZYuWboX9tYnumV@bQMlWMRueA8GnId3ogQH4tgTeY71vdh4uVESIpE9gf/0ofyywP3rdrIuLgenhAqrQsWZgClmOMzFyXQvshiUxr4/bh0dgzBsQ31y5NPaysXVnNMM9aDNyrRtWN8c0yuo/V5mOq5aWrUXiYjIcTTz/sRwHWqIVHYUenpG/d2ECcOkViFY20K3x8pHqyJAraGF@pzh3rtLGPzctp88@L2UYKG2ghKFyvoRx7kH3/BTXBbn2Ek6kvN9z2hMHOiSXF@wV1K2RZZJpm@P1oznjMa4RCp5YGN5z4L4H5RHe5bsfCkE6WU6RR7fr@vMNz7f078B5x87E7RjoDE8xiZoFfq7GXrCmGfeJOHgKy0XUSus4FjQvcFhLm0zHsSdjyZ3Ya3uFwtpeocKmpUKEDVjia/uPnyWj3EBrwG/TQg0w/iaeNZu7Vi4YuMZkpg2K2Go5uhg7sCXu89OXjmgB8i1pdvGIqA6J6/vOMnvn6cw1xu9tMIHwnwzvGx2cNrw17yfOY8d2oDcagaAcHhn8JIGFhR7LE2KyR7hXHujTvTWbYwK7ohPi2oY@MtpQv9bc9T59EQd8Xx/rK7oiGhsk@y903corptU23C9o0C/iXmXSLiL00JiSbbGaYXgblMadDleJcTxuoY0szNh4I8ex@Z2kbQYe6uP1UgW6Arq9/0S5jMv7F8YFltpni0U9POerRIwuP@piVVldo@1Y/L5mTZJt8jUBumsanvIIT04gv0KOSaB9eWtlSHGtDJmbRqDJnuseTdIvNzXmINXpBywBGuhux8GZMN@xZnVO5LiDW8R0uGOALxxoA@GnILH0zsQ/vvE2tKxhe0i3lQZDpDaPjDbuNWrTGSFjfXqzMvnIkH9AQmRFV3isQCCusFEXWOIpWCPJ27utBTtqkarmiG4kqVdOl9NiHck2jc5rHUfNHKLXfGx6IRzKrDwh54qx6kgzolFkRaf980tb0uLSNVBoLEMaD1yw@ZXxuuHt4PCWJfMhk6GBk8yLszArVVfHG1BhneXz6aFwdQ3JP0EQZEl4miDXD6XdlZongof/w3tfVaATbhVywYEmILpun8EH5Ceu7T/ehwOfOt64Z04PAW/cdLBKnGCx8pAEHrxloGtrVSGg9uyJxUcf@pF1V8MumWMSHYMrSRaJ67EhGfa5RMfLTW@WyOFbyZRdPE91bHQl/3QFnGmQHgW7ysJo/nPJBGpUNuJiT1XhhJ0Wcv7yz2XEvQgkA@hbzlgaefRURt7Tg0eHJ/LIU5f2T7sD3IxxQ49bOK5BK2UiQ1Jf6G5kvpMvR@ua3li5d6xKe48OZIywgt58RkOCB87MLTxWjnv6p5fqir7SCsJQY7xcQXx48vhRar7xkyX2Bq4zNJLR4L3j4zRubPnq8dLgaOoH0Dp6znRl8oN9VU0uYd9nNs0OrpKeS3JaBenEAGsUmPEhP@3lVuWq44yM7slsZHwKnSdKcO89sy@sLOQT/dzsYytk5ZWEoobKynIhl4yszAZj23DD56r6PDNHKC079FD4Y@VyFNQcsoqbXa49rJvxv67FsIy/EuHDEqmZm9w6NiVoGf0BuhTd@/sipqrqKjof6z2oV5ZfWVmLEZbND1vO@XtMJRu@8SKFXtIYuEoyb11HXpSGILoVvOHwvO8JzvbKZTDrAITehaUN/sKwZ7ot0VzWOvWiAqlxUdvaKJ8b7zEhFa7wOcczpZfO8YVL6lmiQ87kLRmfuJEke3v3Dm5LcOTTcn2sj588Y091D482WR8xirHxHhjPNaMvJBy3wnP1Vk6ndl0Apa2F1x8tb88Vdqy7XceeTW@fhKOdrdi105HFISx8o0iGZU7NZX1Vh49rPV2@zOi2vPkmDme2oAdHj7zxAb379r9Q1UyGDjTCp5rhr7fUTNDAWQJd@gxPyYsGnRyEoqGDeosMHsml1ugjY4rLUfho8DKjfmn/VljT9xWTq7uTdWGlNWG5NfndCENPlpUz6hqA@TVhLC@HwY8c62LgyHu6a3hL1h8vRWhdQcprClKOSOfXpQwOgtLEou9ereLj1gX/sZRbT4yxmxsNnLaZW1qG3R4eXcke4xHsN8P95RS6S8tb@o6/5YO/L8/vYmIszeix/np5AEmas6VBIASNwYS2RNwMXpwgbYPOa9h9k5/ayO454316W4rkUwdXrC/N8r45uj8ZrUYURCJ@MOC6FF@I@BxMZefCY/dwR9xcO19i8uOyuOX@q1RZFo4H4pmlD092A6Y6PFa0eY58X93RxI6e9Oyl/bM6@HZYvkHRk4PjuBMJO5VKJhe/GxHdjsk3IuJ5gHwPIcR984Zt@FsFISDcPelvUMRjw8B0MXBbr0AgcN9owq7V1HyZ7eDXGyqgmCQpR/Siw5mCvBps89Lf91epqFe491GsiMzflxmetcrPCwW4eNIhlIlJZyrbHEPIZrBrkNHR9@wNI2MHtCs1n4E3WYlu46762ykBpc3LpwdP949Pdk@eHTcyzSsx6W8a5rjZNuQWbCf/KNsVoew@2UCI8tODaduxBdnRsfxoJHlBuRiU7FrRagtFmxdK3ME0m5e2rSi0e1aRrgA/SeS5UShoROjFYQclpvrxNz9X@KZTi0gqbnLQIuUJdVZhmWUZj3QQCJu2H379qyIUyrJZDOUZ@we@QnPoO07Xz9Ez2O1XkOOD3YNHz472WYDgnGkuzO54UCvn@XnAqGhIBtRTz6S1ODUW95PEoa5qtfiDOBAmLsdZhfYs01m8wOcQLaAO7nb2U2@xxCbBBwrGw0pR/us3lKu4jMtKkxA3HiAVZz7lMQI7wX2If/rjLj@rPjh9JPh8jjukRkqnPAj@HuMVO4yRotQwR6s/okNnw9Nm4vBQ@vmHiQT6ZgFw5QUdHHbtUKkknfPCv4jkn/kVZEQMEpxvjeOTeH6X67FzE3cScxx6eJzWIivjkgY6Qk5mu/iFIOB5ptOHEwD1iT3mR9b4B1zEgI/kUKCk2SYhyz@zIEYixrc3gJXbBoht5tlg9BnjCvsC@AzHACt8O7sk1eM3kgSg@aehpMF4aEUi3jh/y1NOXeXdr/wzpV9l4B6D@zu@e5q5B2@/5L/1wP3L3P1CwXq/eV7XHJcoQnjGnl8CjkhIf6R95MNINj9CYE44PFYskJrMHEI1nRPVMTrPgd8lELZzOInGp1BpwG5QY/7RATw/w20m8JC/iqIgS6EqIdOKaWPKly9dO@yvkC/kVAWQlM4DgHQ6dx/3ZXKAyWQFGoFwbo5qL6Gf2t7eZiLaE0atUOU1q2zaL7LiyxDRTYgrXAwQuQaDNJBkngLC6n4y6FpSahKTomyKq3EUS10H@hwKx74J322fECJLALE4jQw87nmKX8gau7Pg0Mo2fnUq8uWGTR@QpEKPQ66kKPi73Z84Y2CfhX3@fLc7Lt/j/RueBufxL8DRWZHIj/LNljXfpBl8IsJvazLKAA4qm7neVUbrVnyOII4RREVcxr6NF@x0fGo3Fc6bDNj0h0uY2Qb3Lyr9FTzLy71786TAxPVz/pBY7O6x7aDh9AAKwxKaomUVtZCcFymXW1okv0R@NlAcPL/kDWQHYgpERscwv3BG3u7e/sFXD58e3zgNj2LGr0cDqV7fTp1KcrrRDB3xaLEWq@TeA@X48b0HQUXMkS5EpDFoMn5J1HUlmY@HIMj5@vrrRVuG4fXSrcb4Od@Bex3frLYONUp0Aw818wH50hpX6QHtVLmeuVZaRq18fh1Kc3hKBPQe32Z4A9VE8vKq0dyun9qx@E1OWNIQXsTkLWwE4Dr1tjYVZPabhcOChV9qPMFPRHnRtphd3hbFzSweyoS7nMfO2fw4Kt8jEhApb5ANiEhBVoKoK1vfIdfA54emafxLkvz4puihNRGEC5l1FI@AOgk@SolSZH7ko3/a4UD3BpbZFoLDgviph8HhbOGBh/ygn0RS8D8cwDNO@J@pnFamMi1oSSRR2hGsNFt3gGIALylAg0bd7ekETKOnzogfJE0Tl/eNwHXkgPgFe4wsHoN9dTKEeD16HBk0iAySW4LEQMl4iCrXpUBK@OcnTlN4QiXk18BTFP2Cy8NuPjFNygNj2jX7INsTyTRItI9UtcnCMxax0HSmoh0Xqc7mtbC2KX6Mm0ejZP@ggzancwT0hi6DNWlME/GLeLLShPzRP37x/DyeFJfxEh346Z@A2b1@8meIflFdL0n0sd86g2M1l0mLcvmmlAC/64D5kVXBV2zKZXngCfRVshrq5cdj9xE4QY1I9Ib6iCUmNj/WS2b0mjhN2Gk6B0mq85MBbZZKkbkEDwqQGaXskYv33wndnrGEUgMmQF/P7uLjtTliDVWWm@CmTJJsE78utQcaFx6RkxTAwoUkFQJbQxYCIwIw4o1E5gwOaTBcwJOLXDocbUkwfWyHxtocpAmVmtXvsMjXwhY1R7FcrvgVuigVywy476Y4lBUAe0POBXo9UNc/ggNoBsatLMTmgvymxItRvjGOyEP/7A5AJxY5zTM40oMBrPlZm52Bi7/Evg1tBU8hqjw7edAqJRWRhWeA9F2zi2PB/EDq0IDzPyECzVRZiBqvcnvtY0yGh7u1@CEjePbYA2ow4jWRGouS4frHd@e8qaprud5P6NcCxMxhB@DvlWoF4PAUw2BWfknYcmH/s5/h533FxKaqnrXc81Q8n6nCTa3mWZ59tHkqSZuNTO3upg5W1PjV9FRkupLbun9uDHrtg75yKoosy3KKshV/sPXU1AovXk2vsmrp1dlILTTkV9OmWKqlz5pT9vTpZ29bb5Pi9HwmnibIsmR7h29ENYeGa6xSZpc7hWzsrIwBwfWaP7RV13WLXYyLLHZ6ip/tFYuiojTiTfinoJdw8UiNulyXd5pv3yYbTNfH0xk7jeGnMNnhXcbISroDQp6BLqklj03TVNjpyOt24ecMWJN/zznGr1QqITHfQ2pwv@pw2iO/6a7R70/29Rn3N2MTfDwY@2kff/78@XN0PKeLvT6K@bA5xCCPSkvPx5iW0f70JxtX6cunre0//eZQMTbwcYiP71w9Rvexmv9oY@Oje/dyuTSQhruffv7067u7u7n76fzTRn4nJ2U2tv/kjzc2NG1bUzaanqc2442zs89ELZMT5T/9Ubz19OnXPK@e/T@@8bau4q0It3NWBDkBV5ap4MR7CX4q6lhn7DVcZz2G/@R@3Y24dXS3e69Z7HUMuFyNzeivNa/kDabWd4r/7XuHr2LjWF1TnrvwHMdexQqlGHeCA96ywdt5rB7bxmiFq9hMqdVq4Cz@t38P6etfBTgYMtuGWz0fwCrMYnWpRknexOoFcKiaBvn@X9/4RoR5uJiokRoXXHdZAy4xV9TEnSZcW3RtC3jympRRlGv8p5buqHcYs8eDseHgw@QP28AjsKUqWN1HjVQq1ZRbElzyC7LdVVU7BQHAFliLWghRyX/lPizqF/KJ7wNhz2PEU8BUxFfc7XsQq3GP59fjPV9yVZ//Y19HozsgA6WPtmo1ifFj@7LZzB08SzhJg3S@V568hFhh465xv16HNNl6dqueomvjtFLhdaWwYkl0nLsgUdIsfirG2Uv2iOqFsbqYKWliOp2@20KfKdJfmsbm1GacoCy2UA0xNn9jUa8YC5KxeZwPjbeP15/9r3/2/T/7Hv19n37/CU@0s7tmT9mCdOeAfZ1f8BTrrnh5Si9Q4EylVCkpravTxBaIteYRUzMfv4nns/Fj/k1n@DtNBkOjsfCq1/FG//4bueh5zc8PqYcvFGOeZH28gKgx6K/9tX9S47zelFDLqkkNtZBvSpx5gzLWy6xxF6pJ1IplsVnX8tohVJ0q8oobbHrMiYG5WYBEO3BtwB/9wxW@buDw8wb5bQQhFOvmtRHme@sFMCvqlpZV8h8V9jUh1mgoTaMJWi@rB0DublQ2SpVCRVNaa@Cy6k0vwzCeerFzVe202@3XnbYOV1vv6OpYvysX5ZKsbU/0qT7Tx@1Je9oedyYdVRVibxsb7Ig3gyZLBddp6tbrmSy3fCc5HPxJkjONCbF/hKuuairbAqmbgRuoGuQESxD/oBwsdglX8@1W4@0WcEg9tU3Ns1mXfCzhIbfuNlPS1VUD3NWq/79dD51VurgLCte8SqW2X9QlqfGi3kgByBc@SJnDlFv1ZjznxAvO3W0KD7P08/RjbTcZZJvabmzXnD36QUq4pCbA3V7A9e7dlAyuu5CyvglaRzKV2pSkDRT4DV9WQeRmPRUUCnEAVWh7GxjgavuqftXYvrra3ob/bbpf@U/wvdq@8U@P@bUizjy8yRpZrQR41eunDaV@qpz6zNeEd1mpo4@snIKjDk@IBz2fEIPmaVSE2BbbiuGJV9nYlhB7@e7L/xl/p@@@/D1UCxj8CTFlC62JMjcq4MbsxzZ7zC8b3PgLXtEHPR7X0dPmNxsnHBTlpcwqfEw3oZYKSRllYcvptXD3rMxeQlSGAoKJWqkgtlLqTGOxbbFQJBHx8zeueDz@T15q5WKcG9@45fOl53mPI5gBnvj3mH70B4mqWkaV1Dd1fsgyP97@55dd/@TnV11C7E0ZqMdA@nmMU0WIQVXEJKkuxOrbQ1waiKPgEhoc57XPpGe7ElrI@pjmODrc@qsd7NfK5TofwN98SryzdX8L7ir8729AaQTsYoTYJd7ar/Dv0Wv8Yycd/Dt6hX/s5DX@HY3xjz1u49/JK/zbbePfyRD/7r3Cv8dj/HvWx7/Tn8tm1aq4eUmkSKll9WpzKhJJqrGd@unP8crqxX/63W9@M16rxaU4nbCfUx2XqckqENPz4tW7cSFWY5vqppqxMp2M2lbb4DBZxmWZQWagdqG7aqksY7DMLDNjmaGjdsFlwF8GXGamxzJ9lrEzNkSEUHCNW5kxunrw6MNfDwC58GfiwpW2mukwyMhCvZM@zYXgwfWmdSo0wIAWXxpgFMiqnJELZhM/aNAQX748VbaaWrnEZOQUudV4eRpv4nG5WjnH2jNj4/Qli3lgVVRjyumpwsdHoKxEjqurVmv/yf1WS0EpevrYOZz/Hx4Oo69r/4eHzuNDZ@jA/@Hh4WNogvXU3RQImLt3ayBw/MdOrF7dOa2QvApkVkzZ3jmtZyV0F1IgjTT0S33gNYcIz/rGqRC/SKBCeIE6YfX5RfW8Su6L4BUcreo8QhCNO/wnXBcgoQPd7wKu8wt00Bs6L56fhi7uUJ5fnKJxBFpg@A9ad/T1H@Df/H/X/@NnLMkSjWYycXm1naAriX/J5OXV5ZV/rycTCf8lsQ1/6AHvmOTyqo5OinQJrkYi2UxeXXE/uCeS2xxgHbLZrlPaeTyQIbEwS8qW3xL/sE/I2r9O41Wmz9ctnJ5OM5lktR2c443zdPobmj5OVumrTJvthtr8kx/Rae07SYqUz1Wr6hbjL1pOq1ZzwVuxVK2WgpfNRKJ886pndtQCaG25XDJZrcLLTgA2A68h2BKADV7yANXw9I4vBS8PDukcc5AS@Rh@KICLhUSGvnaAH86JixXxzp2E/0Hend3knTtaOfPmTegzGoGXuuDVanVNt9VC/@ybN2JLpGUE5Ty8Z0pv3qiZckqNJx038QS/uARZJSSVfaTVKdcyCF8tV0yyf5ALgOW3twu5er2QA3ehhFOeNy@iBhM347HLoAcvJrlojG8qYpVbr9C6PbzY5VWMqp3l8skECNckaIFXMfzj3mq5zP2TLFdIlFJl/6@2kWR1UEn4H5ro2VRuq7h1F5Q1/JsuvVAmVy@NmnpVuzQqONR5Ve3437vEjbvGnTvZMpC1lKmeCq3W/d2T3VarJooi9qpwQ0@S7gJ@ZmvkxhtU5flys4ElbJ7G45XqXWIPtZRnwAd@PCkO3QQrlYkQgtnDXflQekH1B0A2BI2eeBPK/rAIeMawW@e/Llysy9qsjxfrM9M0mcksupjFeDjdO50wksMvPzR8pbR4hT5GeAmxp4929/ZP0tq2xGLag929tHb87F5Mxdf8/J2Cs/h@tL97//AZJHj6aH/3eP/jg0/3nz0Ff49dzK9Azvv3@TPqWvJ@wZ4LX7ivdcPQjYlhtC4mk4tX7AvTbJlQf9YECuH0XeYZLcB9pM/LUYVfx/T0L77Q3RFd7N0Pv/3uh//du9/@7rvf/va73/7@T7/8/rfh92P4fZc/v/vvynm8//TLf/E7737rt8HzP8HvD@H3k59@@evf4D96/yP4/ZeI3x/5v0g8/hMA1i/99Mvv/einX/7yD@D3r/zfD27@fuUny3/f/9bqH6b73u@sj/Pdfw@/3@Wwgrjf/S3uh88b8X@Lx/vlH7z7tf/A///E/0Pnb7/7tT/Cm//yz3/wJ//l3Tf/o6aV/uTfvvvW995965vvvvWdd9/6p9q7X/@3aiZ6@5133//9v/yD3/3LP/gf6f/HdP/d9/l/94N//uf/y5//b3/@B/7vJ/D7D@D6yZ//R2gbf/P7P8T/7/3@3/zhD/H/f/rXf/P7v/o3v/RvyPEb3PF//6t/x@9/9Sv/@a9/8zt/@ZNv/PWv/uSvf@P3//J//@X/89f/81/997/3V//sm@j5Gz/5yz/8pb/45rf/4lv/8i@@@eWK@7fX3r98D/8v/xF83h/P94HzPuX6UJ8v/074/H2oMc8F@AS4@xff/fovAIP/GmPvvv1jXOUOvxX/P9ZUivNj/vb/AYd2s8wYkgEX/H713be/iyT6H4BE8B/S6zvhy0IIf/nO/AXI@ptLEv3iT7/8lz@it5hRqdPoOXbXJa2U2gKTZqtc9rtsf2AdkvzCIrQQgJ/Td1BCLYR9B2Xbux9@492P/um7H/7Gux/@EnaYUq6c3k1L6nq1BnpYKf8e8TBi4X3iYcTPMP8UjQpJqc/gjX3mB3722WdC642C2ynuvgHfz8iLX4wH4XYLPygIQ3/cf8HesKjbd2Z856bvG@ZMWGCuKVI0tgItKJ9l05SP0BSHL/EJ/hBpukXOKd7JF4OnAt7m/3PnVGApjMMv/PpU4CSHn87PgjuFPGSTmk4DcpFaxrgqtMV9aJ6O8s2VGZZgOk1Nwd4FB@SQgqB7KVar1VKYsMbxgVeOWr3ECJVUqgblxtQ8TbpVQhDTewQFUtZSR6y1VZvyhCmEVw/IkRLQ60hUNTFVqt2HDGvT@wxhIXAC@/JlrV6qTesI7i2nR2qaukc4IbBaalp/C@81ggnphNj9t4BKqZZK1UuYIRaSV0@6xSspT4WjsqdYyq8DeOJo9s5dxj4S1ZLY4tohEozHxntqHhsjQnQIP01t@cWh/8BJvy0i@AZl5efCePgOKaI7XDfFCABXkmRZZvCTJMTmLgRPOagUZQuPFIeQIo4gDgg9GA77pIQU1W@KXiD/WG3rgy8EhoXZ3NwUYnUxKx7KRDpFYe5ZhX896A03vSpMLJRF9DZomX2AC6SvUv6bcZyDiDMOmH2U4r@7d7fYR1BMes79BCalsk7OiXEo26mUqAH8upMSXoAFIgCfEqA3gjytkZGTEtJpxuRaDMPY4eGhjwR5vKgJKWBzLaviO06TTCaTGKSQ5bScTvtPmZ7kIfsOmUL9p7yJxKUvljJNy1XBUKoy9GJRq0YFAxg93759C7VC61sqB2CbMn@pi5YrUSB48N3kljULtmNoubLA7XKmFnKMJWgYFK4kSwoswbaSAl8VzZEIrkRcK5XiFA@oLye2gpVPBZXYAYdAY3VENLi4sVjKJ4PAvUO2d/j48f6Tk1GzyQSDvsBqtEau0zE8L4Fhu0/u8/lBrVxIxhoNBH1S0VDACPuVDIm/g/tHB8cVxgvtV0GCEKvSFJRfzLIqxEaj59sxf@WHiJ/7ccRjvFfmZUto5SwkjdWFWMdAiwJ4Cf/hVxUee/17zhRM/rQoptUCmnFJGvhlwtedCcPD6PjOdWhTuE5e3t4mCgj1S4kG6NEJtVUQ6nV/zRRThfrx/gkkODlkqpaRhfpnbCpjhtKVULdqlmH3x4NNXHwknmbESJk2G5k0/mnZLNzVXCGt5ovNjQ3rUsI8T6naLnEV2RW8XkpYjK/AxYSvCOwr4AUX5IFLw5i/Lu/gsOovjsJjXxJ8hZSo5qGZJYVTqGgOThhFr@oI2Bus@shPiG18/vmY1etgS0sHD4QYiIsBCxYISWZXHshUz92Ja1Bon7Gu@amJH3KSu6Y3svQZtB0gR@zq6qoHkA4eMK2u0StP0cX7VYd82uC@mupCzK5Uam/VXFHIaZXK26ymCeAhxF680PV6vZFpXuaKWi6fy2vZQiFf1IBo5VwhX8pm1Ewhk9c0tZzLlUvl4hVLQM3qulSvZbWssKUIMVUUlS0hm80KOGos/P/XrRfNgWyP6kDdbWUETh2cuW1FB2cbnPltpQ1OE5zlbcUE56SeVTPbyqQuMGGbH8TGcJ93TRwbUzz3kfuJdc@wejLutaiJlIEmbvsHm9b9dHXctOLo3RpuBsYNBonkpdCvXdD2OMGo9WXcU@7auiV0a12nQ9@pE7py2@nOZG88s3B7guW4tTjoX/EgwMRP/@JWuJoBCgCOL@1ks7lKgzXlkTPaEbR8MdVQMyC58aeW0lp6w9gpFitduWMZuruTr@RL6S7ufPBngHbymUpf/uzxo4fj8ejIoO0QO7kyJMADWfDohJ1SJZ9vNhqimGpQNk38BiaXC9LGBrQlQ@9K8Ow59tiTtFITEndNt1aLx3eyqiaplWymJFyFFBKAtljAuoApU1iwNNL30m94FduxoZFX0nravCQiVHq93tXWZWr@IuiXEn8D8lxJerp9Gb5WpUi8CpukJXMeCD56Dwh/6c98VUQtXxKrjer8vVgQq80r4e7Q6Jo6boI4zVzeTFUAYcihxiCjUyZcVVzHGVfaRs9xjXnErFoIInKEbkbIiVdhdqcZzPHyZnYFjAQ05JQDZuYn49Vp4V8DBEdzH3rORnM7ODMPmVjTJC0rZVVJzeL/LQ4N/98/vgb/Gt4hVVYTTnDf@BMQ49D12OwR7j8dO@zEcehTjPeMzooYewOdVjjuuY7n/T3i3NPtMx503@SHtYVBD3X8DIs3NMeDFTGejYa45dxw/9Eg7A/bgCC1copwD26u5TjLIhTZs6crSvk4PB4ViMHPR4XoRwcfPzyJPE/2d/ceCgV27/DJ/WuPvB8pzx7tPzgJX4s8NEiaD0F8ff/Ro@uv/iN3@OyoN3Fc/AkPDp/l5rfQCzfQCTm4FiOF3gTEv@ErKTo4qL3B8sXAoQq47PoOGGt3fGe@MHdm0Pmc7w40vXAZMN8GWhFOgi2DOkMB1DZYh58sgNYjnfrj65ZqsSwII2Y7F6yYYV3HsnT8tG1vAzwHOm5/MlDBsugLzJj1heNa3Quza2wIj3GnVVnF73ciEsJDADKcdOiIDeit8Qy5Ln50FmdR2tbEYBP8sPMKT3igFzpdsz@APujCCSIIbV1ntHbnwy5Ib0Sv8XqPMc@D/G6EWDejCzFBFB/qYz1Wqt65oz51xXJW9OqZSqVv1PenwKvsGbQd3Z2lS3lxLIsPmNyK9c2G1xxBdRXUjdPMWSXnjOo6Hnj2apLKNUCXHPc6VejcdnL5ChC4Xsrk/@o3f/y3f/yr0IezUlnr19TTOKq4pCGZvQ1VkEnb1sqlfKmc1UrpUrmUy6uFfD6tamkwVIpl0FUzakktlPJlNV3KlbPAdmUIzZeLQowvigNFi/QtZasCYO0OflZymxR2eQCaOZ88Y68TepLF9PB9wkQD0ogC2kZj2lG6Zdagf2FqhmWLDCDqrMNiDx7sZR48EMV7@IKLBvYyotjFl3wpkyneE0WDQvZKqFiIDk9TwgN6xDF/yWTu7YnihAPAs21FcYAv@wUc3RFFE1/2dh88wHx6@KJheoh2xkP4ixW8FCGajS/ZLAfwKoQG0XZ5PjlCdB9fMEsMecBD9iBMFD8O0MGQIx6NA3gYlHR3VxQP@MvuLobsUbHzHNFP8GWXLlF04QVagCj2wdF3oe2JYhuc2A5EsQOuzkwHP/yEJx5/ao91UZxx8iCBRHFKsfXOmSi2An/M5lMfmzxSt0IvKi/1XXop458oagHSGC0bvmRFMRe@5KBsDx9@qg@AZ/v8mrn82YGSPnyY1c3pZP9B@@OP2/1@253t7n98hEF7ew@hi59N3Ha/7Sdst@ByINXeQ00/G86uX1Dqg1aroltLgz5ptXK6fS2oNWsZiCGkegWY@VcfMxq29iBo72Hrrr5sIpMAtlAEDOHZxuveEJ739DYPCi4Koue03RaryP6oMdP3vaEl0qe200O94zpVfJ/WNhiLJ@LpWaOQaVYpgA1BN85Ur@jD3gm86zgakbycNaa1TLM2rRU1vgimlxBPp1reFNMbwx21nK9s6DuqlktNK7hb3enFWVxSd1hCvbP1miWeJHc0UI7F050dSWyozR1NLVUKxRdbE1FMVvC@ky1WIGImDqY83pKNYnOnmI8kKRZTuqJVisVk9QroMYY@vY2jBK1E4sLQz5JJRBdtVigC/6z4jMppVnuJaXpa43ixWbI6ralVfuIfy9yA1cXjZSedseNyiH0AN93JVOjD5aJaLomQv6IkksnQFFSE@cK75187OTs5@UxASVj3bemn/Gu4Vf/144d7MpjX/hseCys/QMvEceU9FFcLIfzU0sDrBHRz@SF0omCmBH64a8h1LHl/2jFGaN4EAcFhf7J/RJt88nABzvHAueA546brKp3zY3cMhqfmml2m1@rg0rssQVgxPXlB3XerXq@1akP@7fF6mOoTRkfKzsEceBz3cCs4Jb/EnTR@QKuWuaq2a9PYFOC0akxSXw6d7kst1al28bDce7V7mLjagme7atQM/AK7GBOrvR27xtjE9vSe8dRw8ZCDg8NNUCZwe02ix4zkJjul77XvoQZ/JdVdZs8xezIZJsCebycXvSKvSJrE14IiX9J@L1wccFXt1VjiRbL6Cl7dTZboyveSO7lqN3GPtZLgk3nZe9ljGivkqvQVywRCgkZEtKHvoCdr9U9A/@GAzyoVQMSv4zOAiTkBWLNLAXpyZF5VOzWLJSQ2ZUkiT67arzUw9Ru8bUui2JSkxpumUJek50Id2ml1FtNr3qRNJ6yzTFvVMoXqFPzUYq46gIrVX0yrbm00cY2qBa/@wBLf1qZXgZxANQDz@k3i3S98I7kt5Wvcr0qg3ligcrTkVm1atfHMJmCJWrYGAalGLpMGoxZuxTR081ohrRbS2XQuLRXRF/r4dD4NnmDdgEaRsBIiY2I6M83Ialo11HQi89LsvkymzxKgrRDJWDI9dvbx8@/gA5WEXEmv8NRZMqVtWQxqwWH6tkRsCpKiigUDmg/YyEwPENSRoVuUIpmUWHYrYW0mMM7myWS032hWKvvT0dcgKCG92imkipnU62SymthI1jzjlVCvCnWUKlTq0QbwrD/mxrzJsAF1DC61qFUajTYWsZhJZzNZKJ3ZetPfFutiM53ZKKhQRVcoEmIq4xKDq0hzJWfuN2qh1m0ZUHVqWasKMq0jyZY0qazkt/IZPujEUwojX6whJVniVAy2cCbi8aIWjyfjVRwR3xD9IVCQZSTH4iBU43fUHRH0L7EiljWMMBeJtEsvE1XBrgQcEWC5shC7FK4ur7bBpFVo4SDojmyDXJJcvyvEKowpAjv1z4RRNhj70PWIqe36C/48xYXUAFeg0xVB@6R1QoaJdhj7FHck77A4IKa7w4amZZsNrQg9GUjHIKqmqVWcBYjhUm25DiT2LgG/7VQdN/N8wmYzPSUFw9J3GOunNgUqdOz6TN9ubbd/tBusgtrdw4HOU1C0xWpcjF3GY/Er@BNid2kHkcZ3ELFYZA8RH@n@ufjdWDwexyFlINTbGAkJtncZDE1V8GM/Cb3CRUKjmXz7xLQuS1mJDy6AjLq6im0qVDXBJotPXmrAFTHbCTzAIMJBHOit8nkcro0pL0fe51op@/jg0L7vPjAY33NRyrXEeoxlVAn3MFQrvm9ebG2cqcAUWTF7lo6xuzFady2WS5qocY9qjJ1JcbXC92mMjssvii9KLx4/O3x2@ECInW682XBwZJ6Fq8be2l/9GkSMZ3NgJJzWYtNaruqvGavXJXVbw2OYiqwC8r6nFqTMmzrn6zoFFDQIefcLP8hNt0vwrmVUeNe0fEqr19UtjSVjo3df/h6euXG5/@nuIxb39Bn72z/@kVb82z/@17QOK35V9WgcuRiDmOhUC8XY5eXo8vIKLh6WjzVjHKlcMQluPt@gxuqKqmVt266yiqLrW8VUTrtrVxU/rlpUkzFPivkzJ8V8zHvjB2mZEgQFUxvkJRawSmL7R2ZeU@9uI7eo4X4zFv5tG145JsRKj1@@YQxeOvVuv29q5FIUVnkrse230jZ7i7MJb6UN9rJWx9loFXepBYPtW7jBBmec4vWUshVnYP6weuOq2kwxGq4Ha/GFYWzZp9d4/XQDl/Uvem3Z8GdsefSHiQIPD16DN2PrC09MbCUVpdv1T2vaNli@DqywpQBmp8l3v/Drmlb42z/@lTetN63PNLAOy@WCqsV@pv7sZxBhzUkJgWlHsxJ4pAE6QpOQrfgqvNwRhdjERh2Yxw8MRDQJUYMw@zbY9vgmnKPWQ7XU4kdxdRMUbQs3UqdJh6bDcZJVQQh1TdKR3X4nTTDYFn60A5qtcCl8BYOga2U1EKnCV@agwGMInanTaXnWxB3RVocEpVObaXYHkkAOX8FTzjZoA7gvlyUQZcrWzaQcZY@oRhoSGxqeh2emQZcifAWS@Acs4rfIdTyrAGOaNnQEMkYhPCmg24C8m5C3xRO0yDdBpecR0oxjxxPZoEcLXwHVgKhggsbAzG2IUAWZ8xUgAJQh4QM2m2ybZZPs0kylqvMD2a5wfTceXKcH@6QFTIbQurgvP0hcxXjgBfo7ftIL@cKvYVDWIp4BEA6DzxHXwALA5PSGKhgdZPDeoAAWHRqUoKKxO3fmWNVqZjfJqEQI/8wc4QgW1YO9HFcAFlhPH3UrYprhUXfVwDdkO6B4itAFrpP4GXfVSFIm4uuVIMD/ezMtcuS1qqKAKhbAry/eKjpAMkiMZOd12GHbNaZqxSQLke8A7h1CinZuhibh6fQjWfssCLwCDH8WCw7MB0F0Eh0V9Pn2@kZ5Bj3iBE8rx@OSuDDwN7jzA5FQoB2Mg9RhKiiKaVHsnumCuUKT18FJa4msmsRk85PpCA9ata3lcL2zlk/ig1JhbAZPHc8U8/PZoLNQOg5UqDdybDqEjA5JwYXpwBEgo/zzmzjaE/sCv27h1w0ljmLk0dlNyPmIMR2qRp8FpbQ4e9x2waYNaJNmRl9mnWGXaWWWIEajc6bsEFySEhHCbdB9kcZtyxgCSseGQbuOvIqi9EFzmrTpsK3HJvDV4IEJvYrtKf4XWJUL88xUTvB0bsnp4eYkfnRBDJUtbH58oto/2MpynDNmmWcGH@xNLBz84DHQ/kGBTQNl5z8gbAVXQGjZNMtAcJrHgl8RHkXuLKUjaTcSs@TNZ1bdSLSwRt9QJ2O6@HXVc92O0JeuN4Jv8HozLzg6hg5AgXc5FLmGf2hELY7bwcPTUAT/EJwanb8i4yTCKAHmZ3B4DDqFkWucMzRdBexjQGh2gmMYsBVDab9CHQC1PWhZeKbc2K3g4SGAidtNdKDp@QLeZh@xrCZgRH6yj38KD8DAqq8tQocwSIrl8MZdqBiZRs5RrkDrHHYhDLet@@yH6QPuRjed9zdnb7bhg8NOh/KqMd4sgpd85AVbB/IzFX0DAguA4RJMNhJiCsCmxKTIQYfpryfn3C6QLKmwm5DSDCH4pAYopCoEn19mkc9QCBBwT/f4WcX@iXMXFxcyHYM4cU3Z8PDTDB5@U1oZ9U1Qlx1lbAxH/kfwTPz4qQ937pL4F1nwS@M7U/rGd/nOjD8FoefV/HUkiXjPi2PneI5fHugP6cgkPKvII4Z6YNJXSzoJf1kL5z@tmb4M@K@C/CeV4lcIhDEEM03P0p00AEu3O2fp3kW36gecU4ME4FCLRuCJR4@6wcvQC1zmqBfGcMYoR8OgtnVGE6IASeQDtPOseQmDmLPg1X8fmVNIZBsXbNd19VmCwpMYGxk4MSO1h82g26cQcEI3wy75OZjmtDFrLiSfhsmhUwusIebieUjC5Xqg/FBUDJ/y8CmET3n4dJ5pkG1j2uQqGXpdYXGQ6/EYvSAmgpkFca74AaLzEIIMOjZTOQiMOVvwu4Jfp0apA3rzN6jHWsAYwBMjILiRUBovThunTdszLraaKaUPzC4SIaDGAXSjSTS96IZupL51bo0cb8HLxtMToVfy8UavzsDnBs4rWMawgogxOL1MPPCuP/QXEnCFwC8wQEA9DAJRNdgdJ8xkNTyElwKBcRrinMYcsYaPTJO0Lz/I9wN1iZOeEzYKqBkBhP5hkQBNCGFBy@Ef4gmkw3PXgThBXIm@HTLEg5fizThQ8lpT4bKmSpUUwUqSAjSB7Kiu1q4XJQiHqmhcC4oU88qv/yj6Gx@Mfg/axXLsiWF5h1EVok0FF82BCuE3F6Iqq9ci9QoYKFu6ZbjQc@1z/dTvrSGbLSUwM3g@WATvAr8unIhUfifJ64c25om2WAlZYVarQRFnNd4sebsISMoJHibz/GSzgBH89FyAAIzM0mSGn2waTTat1bjgYNMVyS4iSE4JySlPwmNPVyDZ9JOB9RR@lh6rpwnaKa7qEwGeyrtRUINGIsNPDOO89hd4KBxYVUGec5lDXODzEKrYyGed5tLcGxGkI0LrGgBkxBsAuvybfhXhusBTpfAtlFGclIGM4m8@G3BZAQxGIrjKD05NhExGNjAo/GKK@gFou2KqIYgqjfLiX4b/xHTgGfzUm56ZxZjqomcmfe3vH8WziZSNNNCI9qFmciiQ0ZJ5ZvsnDkZ1jhh@/nbggFbXvnBYYomyDf7KxE@qtC2nrQx1XJ@CX/ryv349miUD@wFnSNjdkTPWx04uV@FGk0lstyx/bjOYfdvBDwREDk8GXa/rGJ4dH0Oldpy@bXpGmuG5dmeGb3YY/onxQlRP9p2OJwj@8CQ3YxE05ytUdVst/PZoq5XABXjJSri6l9bjIXvG4wLav@CKpAfx5AM9HCWc9hdGZ5y8HSae8@0nOzE7Z4nDkR@IQ6m7DGRYB/R/CB2ABsM8Z2450inDqEq3xwk6JX/gDJ0@aH0TTxYw9TXwB3PYiJA@GhEuaaajSVuJnPZOrSTRSetJP@knH5yUfaIl9GSYXlsEsECMNHOv0xgp6y7JrrUyO54syO/4w/E9juJ7vB5fssKv48xN8xoP/LCss4k5BIg4RyN7OxpYdJBb3RvoLKASeqNexRO8N4pdWv/VRUx3IequH13uAX@kwzcP3kLEP11F//UVGCTff9/q0/GDzMczkDdDXJaYoG@6eMFUZwKiHySTQmxJdiFr33/PvCAufk7rAaoQoMaS4LLxgFRomCMwu73wCP8A8C08j0uubvA9rcOq8cAlOLnnaXamra6i@62uYekzo5vwY6YjcIMSH4HBRvLq/QqOgo6EnsNtvQT0XckwFLpxJDqPVFnBMnr6PJlczVY8ihlyD42UE4YHq@mH4TdEMw7x1fhoNdgB8XgMh2PPTRz@HM1GM34Gt8W/7OHLUd7/8JrE0wduJwjQgfeeanqebXKd@DxKhEV6jx4hjCsvFhmPyA0g4tk6N@vww0h0e0mhciOJakEtC4vfllhe4@a6Go9wRcCTfArp/VjyNqZ7b56LsBoHNhdhex/WhdyAjKszOp1EFCL3WVtjjn1DJqAfjdPZK3qV1hKBGqYkSTc2ydwm/SIpoGV8AE8ccPoUngiwb4xbnKGCsuGYlv@NLEYhQ30U0Vp8H1DSAUqEipzkPhqRWELghuiXV2GenZV5dm7k2VnIM2wBi1lGIgmdhSz9WsDqWVcFltEbr5DOGIS2MzzWiW24bEd3cbTiMm7GK2aaxc/jFRDIcSNe2U@AUI5345X75PDilWNynMUrn4Bj3rbib@KVoFlgBBdeyXEX/X0Rju@deGUvkbwSxvqZ4QX5yvFKWKcQZ4e/EkWAFFhu0Bpxis12/GKOXQM6NlIq0ww5xkuj@UTjMGn6ZeCffy2GvjSBgTjGuUWRWYqpC51GpMfg@UC3EZxkvqQlV/zefP/wAa1uCqNgNimw8aJpCDyo4bH4ojDiiGEozWjAExBEuVlZjhGL9GTviY6fO3AoVfJi/kQ9mfSBboLCGxC5Oc@EPhHkpw/qaxEEr8D3wxMTr8LzBjpBdoQRzskml6CFRH0ZX1MorOtFXPzaj9YQjXUvRsIvmgdReC0R2IhMBx2OJucws5EzWmQSCsVV9GY0DQ3K8UaJ3HstGUkFv2WuCCZvv2QoGKKNP7muOJF0iNqCCMLARqbJW1nYL5AsxqC5rItoqrzxAQoRmQMt3Oic0eeX7vtOisfFTZr6ilXdUJCWZ0mSa1FMQmIZj3Oa6GOee2i87uMhTx9mvgYppzjWkkAAkZRhLly@Oh@gvztcfw8U6oAI1zJYplgv70pvqtdre9lrmFvzbG9WIAam2f3kUuUozGFOcrAOIpr5Ol67oeLjkg@u5PNMQ@jXtP2AbKFNcAvdrtsWHBZqCe75oueZBp5n2mpC3dRIrHM5UFpkzMmHwwseYjov2npcecGXVTGG0Pi2bn1wBbuLFRytPIRHBXCvkZy3cndi0yqXedsGsc19UKSqFcYFOU2XhtU89wRxT1O34bQteBy2ju4fPnn0deh0i8Vi0u@jZ3P8sNXiWGvYj3PItFQ67A@WmC1aGr@igpPdOBzvDRx3vHFqizdkCRfWoAzokEvAfn4bT/qyLCLPr7VdSMfjRijqwzqbNwN9QSqhqqNjl236dB0DQYxxYkv3gQTqLdA7TdZakr4X0mrhF@NbLeq@Wi1cvNRq@b0YVk0wI578WWxDmXgufWOTf@zmQhDo3AJ2/5A9f7h7wk4e7rMHz/Y@YV8/fMae7z45wS3rT5/de3Swx@C3/@R4nwkLSyjxw2BoUAJd7xsdA7/lyLRMJscI8p4zmnG5k9hLcv9jfcgeOh0Dp6m2PX14d8BfZNsY13mqfTBHZziGadKH4IbmGNdb0JfLwIxF5aZLO/9wZT@DuG2waYdo8w6drtkzIa6Atu/INLxgsxizTKhBkLfBNuA0V5LwI2W0dIg@LYgrsC4guQ7xce4GwOh8/RWSGGPwr5p1ZeYTLrw@mIIn@0ePjxmefrB3@OT@wcnB4ZNj9uDwCF6ffv3gycdAz4Pjk6ODe88wiCI@Prx/8OBgb5c8OAIZmeGxBF9MvPFaFGSMTlTpnOHMtzyC6g/fFke9UYNnFzrtgfRYfGKj9DF1y3xtdONVYeKh@oL7LmmqgCU2d48@/hT6fGa8whnOYCqY1h@Izzz6cN5mhm1TbtBY6tDeqkJwzmBCUpM0H/H/FHe9W23sSP4z/RSKTYIb2v9IICTGJAZM4lkSMvxJbg4QX2O3oeca29dtwL4J98zuh32B3e/7CPsq8w7zaZ9it35VUrfaNoQ72XMm5wR3t6RSqVQqSaWq0uVY4e4Mv8ThCjL87CkDnI14WoGvUluwUYHuW6Ia8Fg2oKmiRwQboIzBSlnxnTcLC946g9yg2pqdHgJQSm1iRKhfUPS1MTUpOUwxbSsDoPBeqHWhDyqWog/E9/RhWVc7HEgG9TT6IBnUM/mApWgNtiNqRee4Gu5dQTyrVfnwl8v@Dh8Lq@fRh80G72LXNE7Sb9ylDRXdGYYYDx2@2Ui0PHz7YiNsBgEXCTk/bv3pdGRg@HLfHMlEOUpk2zbKmSJh08ZRgzZ7k0takUrcADuhRnsYqkzZzalDGAf53UDulDrvNLpiAhWb7jDvqTWE0ylv6OVDdBcT@4P0e8yAuAcuiUdUbluvCv2HlqOSm1M1NrSNJN@HaEzQvofA5hQC/wgYApRN7HSaPFOxWyrA9NqalTNhjzgSetvf7fzEzq2rpp8ooK22Mn8JfvvN1UT2EvskY6fI2FEX/eYPaFnJR5nt3oDGOItVvr0GUrB50esPA@nDTLIFfOLE0xzlxsRGtf1siKtrAx0ma@z2ulalZ8TFd9R6Rkz5kFqZ4@XsPBJf8bWmxPk0CYvdHdBpnPWufevszMMh0o0P9QsthPmsHMrP8ZAxkfWnE8uO3xVuQ1wrb2xvnmR//9nDlYgiFuRGUmN0iP/EmKiLhgef87HB4gDrLj3SzFVW4dUZSmsbPC0tMcoNMNoHXgS0r3tdL0VpYm48/R0eM5Pf@eO3b2UplYVk0pfUhheZWLp56thU6XGZU6VNQCzZSciSrM@YLx7DjOT1a3jJoBdKRJEu5Aj27RMXRWkRYlp3dtUmyaLv69TdHcF31QZbVMRXGcP7xe6P/JfMZnlpw83HBiXKImfGiGjPQC66rmWWwvPVFLjt@8GR/H44uLV7sZPp4Q9B274X2h/CLbt0NyyZlixYDwf7@z1gZXL7h8BS2727AcskOQ0t4vSIOb35dGRNe3@NP0/1HY89AoO5FxqUCKhV21WXj6hNvOeMFHBtMPGC6OBwu7q/r1KyP6GyJPewZWhpMQjYj9SH2No26LKwy0WLJjtIsyyezJeERZv5d99gnkm8O0SFXoN4mh6RsIgv7W4HI5F6embhJQRb37NANJRLYvfVyKDwWAO@pT0gIRt3mtVAZ2Yz0zL5BKFtBK7p5sna2LbhZwtrmbtxC@ZgbAOybYIa5/Asmd1/n2R9/NLUIwssxPZBg1u0kqb5hvYJB1RxnzLmcskevKdbTJfCyF4W2GlDOxh@FZIr7B9nKGYkWYTLWtgS63pxrFGT9fG8WeawQSKmgQYsPXWiWDRTghHx/GXd7lA3nvQyySmIFpm4F/G1zRVU/PRWT2FMjWieLEcLcnuszTM2xwbLU2hnNezS3ZkewxZ6dVI8TFZF0vbeqrL/P1XJLJGoydB8ZmNMIkFeXVl5@j3Yk60wxbM/ClvmkEn5Obzs0/4@BhmOQ1bvE@fW3nsmPWaAe0gnpvVmwEwUpKXOjDkl0XaejGz8CBfRCxEyiH6OqyYna3XVaAK32dBlRrKhc5apNlhDOGqojJop6t/eXx0E8nfre/TH65PBhkwwHbyFVf673iD0Y688K1KL9Qmurclv/mDQ5Wziz3QJKBl2Y7rX2Y697cTgVVqFRD5vs1vS1t5JYnbrGV0DV8LqxRxul4V2rzSp3ssWS3ZTd2q7VbXIURHbCV1kapByLdnzKOjehwDLYNZLYPpgH77H4Uv6Tzh4BiSRib35Mkwb97u4MUVo1XzMt99os1AtW4uTvd8Om40uAnx4qcehSnlPqCBrYat7O@4szXqhlChPyIX9boZKealsLsVF6RsUuoCUBCG9ie/WhAVPDWMpCfea8x7so3Cw5Y9Ee8aWk418ca2w@sLh1nW9oXd5/OLUW2yWU4om30b3Mrwa3LR@Oe9dXLdVR/X/cjZqjn/7VamVZ@opLhN9IqFpi6vlPEcDfU5/19SLAnOuRvAVh9k9SSmVk6sFlVpQ8T689EjJvRq8aX4JD4kJLlWLl4YL4WI3LF8er56Wu@VC6fK4e1qCk99wqTxcKi5l8OEJzaIkY@Rk/nh4ijnV1rr63WuF62n5ZkDtGqLYNYS@vGsMgt5u5f2bhDYOCwCowLStNyvU5WbZOVizwfck1/VvMlpN5ilwrIMFkjPHXkFF@L2zPhnqmFZAmFGveLSaDUf8d@w6c4XcVX/Y4xQTdRCspb4F35w548ZUYI0CZTkOTGxC@BcQnDhPBgdD8nUsVtTZoizXivCddC0QxyjJ4jB1kkrBpxCIal@u41MnzPmN5gWQwFXK37iYWl/ni5WJ1cIca/FgytEYsMNE4RSPOAChnz6fNqAKXrmH7PbhUPPxXsSDfGEd1ZD9ZNhA3uGVIlJg/q2@sn8Tl18nAgjh52TNldMqTr3yooWk@A6ycgGxy5IbfxwzwK1SOmUOjQVsqa8cA2dLcaYRqtVkou9zNyCn0Ir@6RZki/w21YwovyvZmSR8Tq3fQtCSu5STNvDTiYtlrGJZU8xktkgx911qQNNF26N3Pg2rsdryOx1CWmgxF5MDj@zfq@tfiuoPj1HnaYS8pGen0rOJ9JykC1JxrhxN8HGml3amVPprnO9WpeJs3lRdZcWLlxz1dDNHS5I4b@m@vGFu2KsHceaNqCuFK6OE9URC1kr5MqP3JeVRokzE4FH6saRr/l7WPR9hmcj7Olk/fh3dQT4bz2pbkwkuzXWDzitH38KrU8BmKaKmUlKcb@BTZlCVtQ@mFie0goOen4ftRjmGslQ0EofHTGpj/XUqpxcZrzKTaIgX49TAmjFGLCpxnUtMuBE7LFI9nPzIAsEwwWjKjNwNU3isC48tsMj1yFQrXpBTA5yaNjnEy/CL/IY/ZrAnkTP50rMT5wTzkTRevJuTBGKh@yg1m0xJaQJ3EfmoG3XPLBLXPZ6EOFtIvLe0wFGdvvhgt6EGfxTJCVtQGEkxRfcoRVM6zlA07HtXFyLx1vnf/KLzpkFr7H7HH6kKthkN9sJyEg7uQz8choj0xPFqwqt@v4NTR17w3bALtY4ZsryC45YYojWz55waLHskv4cn7ZBOhXJqD5BvYCASJ4RX5@dwJoMHbO8GohUal2CYcyrdsSg0aMw8XRY3c19dhXJqSrv9cxsJ6TkZPaB02G80/ZxDa7SQVj@ONLUd6JsrWZ8OvxHEEqMp7aXj/PkqaP6y9Qbnuc@LhadFi2TX@ji4kHv6LHawIiKZhGXEAVwpPnMc62y4KWfDWQD01C4m@o/Em/613@36ToVmDM4Y0qI19AfXfivnOPt@dAgMuGBlnEzCD7t3NWiKcocWXQ1iRngJh54chxGH4RfzsxwXN/mszHNwaBWfNlNXXwctENB4nLR7OB3mAwuECRB6oNClPySiLLoqiRKfPWtceO1yCUUUUQNxTqyziYgM3d4waFLPsCbL6RAoOQaJK@u2JjCh@pqdBpyDc7MQgHtMTAGDgDlKug8HRx@a/yEclG6YOWNvmJ7Jk/Tr8Vih4e4PApK@MYG5V7iYhTt18OHb2oE62Ns5/FTZryp6/rC/97G2Xd1Wm5/5jBsH5RxYV73d2yXpEp2my6n5Hn1IVQ6oZIoTnMr7z6r604f96sGB2ttXtXcfdmsEjcDvV94f1qoHnqq939o92ubTd4Kg3u8dqt3au9ohZTvc87hWU8yJy6m9HfWuur/1ll4rm7Xd2uFnrnGndvgeleFUv6I@VPYPa1tHu5V99eFo/8PeQVWhYc527WBrt1J7V93OUf1Up6p@rL4/VAdvK7u7Ew3d@/S@uq/YSMBq5WaVsKxs0hYWNXE7t2v71a1DNCh@2iLiEYK7njr4UN2q4aH6U5WaU9n/7GmgB9U/H1EmSlTblXeVN9Q4J/MdqlC/bB3tVxEKCZQ4ONo8OKwdHh1W1Zu9vW2m9UF1/2Ntq3pQUs7u3gET7Oig6ilczsdVEwyiFqXT8@bRQY3pVnt/SHPG0QfYO7jUyZ@IMIRlhYpuM4FhBoHWEpH29j8DKujAHeCpT2@r9H0fNGVqVUAFWFRsHdrZqEIi4qHdTPW@@ma39qb6fquK5D2A@VQ7qLrUYbUDZKjBIOMzsQ5VesStRj8RXvJIzOoYzvW4O1VtR1W2P9aAuc5NHHBQ09zCZNt6q2meQ6hdS4kS9KAzaFzaipX29KdrH6EmpzUys3U0UcSkrb3tKs3IOm5VKk44ollnbSKUkp1GM02USK@JkDUt/@zqvB502z34mEbFRPFxGZ57uIfGxSUeJ8491zBp/QoXSKfr9Y@VOm10D@p113tIyQQa3yuh1eD35XJ1G3HpAHbeUPy8fCl0X08QauOJPuhkQz0cQCCnUP@JmL41Ln1X5fMtXxeD8z4AG9VRKMcmFzhKIdHIzo64fSSukjUT/B5oduCCGQM@16xDTwrLSM7UC@lP91v8IpOD9YGks6i78nlsYhmN4DffVCOVcEgE/qMjEgRtrjIX@v4v55mCXR32/LnzXq@VcV1ThvMOaR94nnG/U/zMP58onp0sz8jysbMO5B@afTcvYaLzZ00ypfslN@CWZfCnPuQf12AjMR@gNeWqWFmtlZaZJ1IcFkme0qEt4F7BnYw137vKT7VP2M0Vlp@VJr6/jb7L2IK9IELS0oR3zOVO@eftqWSgAcaxOIgkgY6Qkc9bZYy9SZT5hjJeINNN0ILlD83VFz7P60QSWsheNTp2nZiNB8HIxp7k8Jv9yrvNo50dEp3A9tnayvPVkhOF3frJk9/PqIfjxnLUsT7N47RO4yRrlGzRwodHihWvO2Z/ZuB8HhkRkN10Gn9EnIfIbiNpyQRBhuaGuIqnCxO9lA86pBQH4HjkGH6dOTI1A2QSTXXRmsvGiJf4DVorMQ9oY5bOmHtthD@AHQ1/M8SjBmkG0izGkXSJc2l3wXIvtWNMRXlzw4F7kCWXMnwsYdwiGrCqi@1n4V3Lb5q3rV4MxZQR45W7nUsSEo8msVDGrqIrI/sDxxnRCmCOHkZfftL8Ro@fdYA7DnfXCIeV4QGRcScqCT11rIzWjT7WkE9xqw6Cqpma1hW0/K5GiseeVidHgUGs0cCo4BIU2PgmAZeiOCKTVbIF7OsFV30VTkXwDsApaY7V78S5s5qjoZRM/BD9bqJSKIEVBTkRqt1EdTgmy@cojoUhZ4JMP0QPhv9PpMkM@Ou04yToMbWsIIAPoiRDFVrR9pWJEtyYgwbrdCOmpv3pcwzm1u6Yi6hh@vRmJP41RALdO2Pz4TOHPWxnZhAATA7Fhj1@I5O0iwZtnV6nXF0c5yTd5mU/o/RcYaaKKbjZ1VOPl12eOVvBi6tc0TVZFe5SUfVaNm5nPOppyzSxlVePw5SAc038j/wiK0CiAc9ceiFWq5OcVdCjzMgBHWrJmnBaUcQkWpbe3nlqt6isEJkJ2a9PvgyhCPQG8JluJ98U0lNinpuMuMgzsTrkKHiIDo5tMiYfHbLujA0xOz7gPG6xMgSXiQxvMEF0BDqH6ouhqcxjNhRBJbHVYRxnEOLWzRFpeVq9ibBnzSQ4NML@qCth6X3RapkcOQnwoTG03eVz6l1jTCh3HtZsYbH84kHPg@0iKhO1hC6Pi1Oavd6Alo4NtJtw9IKxm1OftNLB74ZXAx2/kOazYKA1EmbRT9Vg2SS7d55mJCI8oxYGQ3grtHLMH9ykSx8WohKeZJRdVRliXsOjG0bpGIyWiiqzHqesE004LCkTcV2tqm/fJJcQVIcM9ZmCQRhtLthmk@vBuUM0/G56g18w92MJ1G35rSgyqQWSdYHSSbUux3hsDqXp/V7IGg3qCmhAIkoURZEWGarSHP1cs5O2a0rF0TERu5Rb8sfriZjUWEtRRTHj6tqJ@Vaz1Jmg0rIODRoFCy0urzAqszZct3duxjhaaPLYWqVOupFIeSmLiPJjs3TEk8jN6OkznrSSv/w4xOihLzjj1ktQIIw1K85Vp@Uc4webgk@BP2jZOlFaybQafajfeOvT6zIvGtWhDvvXbAxDf0w7gGY@GOUZRj3zp95Ft77V6zTOg17QoH0agrqPROLhccyP6LDzQe8m5DuBOKFlZWqN42eJLyNh2PAenUuWrNBc4dDvZ2wzheFgXLmQMBGsOYcRYHw/JvN3fzJGWlTm2UpcyEn6n7I9XtEt3Vn2aXFWYTnRBwAt4DYmLCjEh3TIjkmW82lpKsPZfRksHM9UVjXcOyz2Ehi/IBLxMUwCY4PMlFmC3QjszO7E@Lg18locg3CAQEv@to@LbcIMf/YauHKYpMgrWAq8VMW1glVUTlFGiEOIh/Hd5F5@/k/GnhD4AfSLT2dxyyxGYBHXNtGWQtmv6CijhAubBwYso1kSkxQLzoOu5X7IV0qMJqEmk8d3UYMtf2hRpMPsTXElRmSGNj64ui5TJ5FTH7uYVBbUgstxO7AEqQwzhbsZ1v@e/SwPfhziiuYMgmlLQ85YSN9FqiZRCZe6TpjX2ihLTOXvj5jl5Yf22gQBy7NMzqzLhTMps3JhD5RA5lcca/UGJIxTE9TTph4L4bDXX3gg9e6UHTMjs82iddN1v2sILMxWpslyscWkLY/xOC45k/hMME2SYmxpRjyE7Ss/R2w@ScRRuY7xVq6Pv0OHu2gW201Fk0rU3y0Z@5gUr2HRayaaaEgx7ghSWoq@H9ep4fW7JYiGKdurOkuMOkRGfSyPFqgJMkVUejiFmPs07hP0aBHlUG@LaGf3z51EnTSSMyFPTVIiyCXoicDtcNokudRvw/gCYeJkhRsJqWjBOfLGfJRXzJ4hyDASBCBWxX421kOJBjfurAk@4tsB2pk6rIWKkET0tGFbOERB/yOCcVR@rdzRFg/1cbZ4WhJIowgS7So4132QjL85vR7XRwxlihQ0xGeQImrRlGy6eHirfrQtlI8gSGlO1pa@BQ@NcdUSYUN/7KT6CGvguCpdMjGikgOhzqKBxgLtUs47vmxXsfoLBsLxsG7Qw4g2EPI5g58lXQLhvFcLEbVRZNQaI4uryS2jzVXZDSkSM5S8g/x6KMpSlzeuBMAXjKl8uUgQENaUscehAIfesTkvgajuIypYLmJY0keOihrbec5IB1F1hmcrVo7CrBwvbBjZmUBoYTE7T4wIrVlmZ4mh0EQ3Excrx/PZ7Ylz0ILY8L5QnLpC90qShlHPCQH5UuWCG0uU46LyCpqDOfHZiptIjPibU18UrNTCZCrRJ8LwOFucTF0rJFIT1S4vJ4smShI9XLvWRCKRwrURjqTCj/1j1xQ75HlkE2ptMhKrDG2fjUuvaZdJ@7bcX0K1zk7ZZo1h4Nme4Wb7VZcrVhJB2e8PwK4W@MgAsdt/uLXGMtVgou8K4Lh0xtklIxtCXrGmMNWjWdjpmkh7UYACs6fttdXHw52dRNjXs7ExNLr0ByuFQgFMfGYHvze21VAlBb18Mne@fdXp5Ps3fxp8PMuz7Pd9vhLgpdlB@9QlNCjCXG9wLjdDAAfKitxZ7ciKvf5Vu21fwYATSnQedZvk1NEQFE9AQWT08vGQFUAMUk@wP6OBaN/PKhp9Nw1ZaGoo5hiKSsMk@DplTs@IPPjQhn12dFLFwCCYjTUTzVtueeMrZhDcbMKdxeGL3a@xeXLqrd/p9Dz1CbcKI1LA3O1kgZ0du0BBsuCEkb17r0KOR@sp/zroWH7FyGLzOsCZicncM2HiwiM2/r5/Xh31M6njLymaVqjJS2jmEuJTeyp1nnJ1sPgHgBU@JLQflPuy0c80mU6TmWmq1yM4fiKMnha9mXufRBaXdWKaZt/PDaLORjfHwRqo6S6vBUwse@5ebskd2SPipk5GxTZoWBAYGifEXHlYCbia/fPE4vWw3X6YVORrAKRj/5BElJtQfkwg8hkAj0A9/IieiKL9L1ka1jsTAUVkgYPLOqblDgrUUcBxHjfLv95kKpWKmu8vLalKZZMesllV2ayobXzY3FTb9L6J9yfl5ZWVksjcbfcrfdw0H2/VJsFgDedS82KwTa@UVobfGKy10cXz@fK8V5qvl9c3SmH@uLIJt356@vu//vvf/@0/8hX98l942eSX4y9Rplwul59vfp1/clvC@/H26cL82fF8/3ThvAQu@1@OGt6rDbON2Hw0Nzhz0jILWF/ZjtTsszn6jC6qzIV/l43BLyRdXqp0M8yn9ddQbo5iGZtu@tZ3H36UZ7SFN5cOTG7lCYk0AR1DHU@90/RhgEfzDVGScIEdqJSXsxWjuEc4mChDdKqS1pF4eM167cOnJY6kAF9cmrGyQTf0u9CAX/OaV5rnOA36DYZ1zb/5L@/C883eSC2eZNRiQS16ajGV4p/i6gv66s7nA3jnSjbaDqRSHqXERwswM1RhwAs93j/wXTsT5Haceb6yB5BMmArOLF5wXrT7Y2cZuXAtPHfmcLGmEhUJHzKhSPrrfPeWuuUr5bhNJVxteKFQ17sYrsw6UYn6F0ugRiiGAHHNl0KQlz2qEid97JGMp7z5ovva4duEGDDIuv9mh8c9PtBcNN/VNs@JvRSuOWLzefmKubEkztCMNlKk/hgBPlCR7WSBPQkX0guOWHlbreRmihe23T7NfGLrMPaHxjZdCv2uLCYQa26bcPNd7deiDbnleEWlguh4xaoqNWn7rRyryOVVZxj0tbsC144B9TWq7VZGEnqUAQkcidn/cnqEsaLARIqa6Ba5LGusWj00XUZCV7umUwe7OTk5soiQ/5Khsf1tYmy7efYSMewgPMBIRaZ87UbQCXXUlQET@7wxOMPtgI02X6g2lHMz1ufhKtUJjHvtCOkcQ2aT83g8U1PS/UHj/LLhqfT73uGgMa7RtEUrn2Ez51ILEYIJSGDw6apnNc8gLC3SXcIUiZrClkO4vKAz1tejSd@mIp8TdKkZCjrsCgZBgp2Ykv63RF9N0DHm6j/QCTbKU8I7Oo3UIpYlLyyNNKSU7TbDw2xq6DimBnvsRAMn5Qiq0cg0vKALXWGiveSDX5LkHcQI0HWntBegdkVYfYH6MTud@91GYnLqdxzj6J8vKZkXMZ75KkqxRnLMJajF@MY7YEXryC/JKBAyN5lwRs5cJjN3Eurr3NL2PMJBviNb/HxDBdEFdHyBGXuGqKNuIMJyYoaK78DIqRpb/hOEdqdxTviNbxpjsOJJOvPqUd49/nLSPV3MnHS/nfzmMiZaJJtZNqvS@jDbSCw9VmhmzHuJV2OVFppQgyfdZIaTrhIfFosEhEg@c/wlf/otTwidpHHD/ElaCJLoMmCSv7@@PMDnp9BMJ7HIp505d9E1nZ95VXQVza38iz6UD678EhZmU8lqetrnDNoEiv10f70Sl5Mwv7ZceLZcfEY7oXN/lB34V5hvs@HVmT@ipUSI7SxNPSe/JbghQYjbUdgo0ccRtVOuNRHfk1A7KWkRqoc51@NEbEVlcsITlJ@ozOFS4eLiRnkaOHzEht9TxHImL8eCEtNBi/symD/D3iXqaYSQa5PeIcKRsDIQGxFWoWYB2Vy@cheHuma4LLCfU05tIXYrA6Huzaet2aLb62b1Ys3NLZSwiIbXTGetsFaYHKNTQzQxQuf1YmrhkSpuvHr@t//c@zU9TG8s5z8N6HeY/jW9upaWR3qgt6fm7Tq9kV5HttXb9DhPe2B6fP63/6byG38iOEgZr9OfjRUDa3Wc3siWuci39MYqPRSXl6ne//nrX6kN87Jjw12s83VPMWIlQ5GtRpd5l9JVDa2UbelCLFbYMQswxMKQ9ub0AsOo0fJagdV0aW1Vce3ryFfGHkVP8WyYNWRTIdFkGHsKWhlJgTIqyApIY0LRVpbthjHbAPPGaKqfH@dWQ9oB/KzNOaIqI9ONxyFMhuZlW0QdmJEaaT8vDxuFV6nIvONlytiUlMwSEls7LWvXnpb@Dw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/kxfgd)

I use OS/2 4.5 preinstalled image from [here](https://gekk.info/os2_ovas/os2_warp_4_5.ova) \$\small(VirtualBox > File > Import Appliance)\$.

Command line: `cmd /c polyglot.cmd /q 2> nul`

File extension must be `.cmd`, `.bat` files are treated as DOS batch files. OS/2 files can also have attributes
indicating OS/2 or DOS batch file (42 and 41 respectively), but those are ignored.

`/c` and `/q` work the same as in Windows cmd except `/q` (=echo off) must be after file name.
OS/2 cmd "steals" first `/q` from batch file arguments, so for example in `tst.cmd /a /q /b` `%1==/a` and `%2==/b`.

`&:` to comment out the rest of the line doesn't work in OS/2 batch, I use `&rem` instead (on line 2).

OS/2 cmd cannot handle lines longer than 1024 bytes, even if those lines are skipped with `goto`. However, longer lines
can be after `exit`. So I placed the code before the longest line. This answer puts hard limit on the length of the
first line, it cannot be longer than 1024 bytes now. In current solution 2nd and 3rd line also have this
restriction.

OS/2 cmd doesn't support `%*`, it is always expanded to `*`.

Windows/OS/2 Batch code is on line 3:

```
...p&if -%*==- (echo 330&exit)else echo 335&exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## 336. Windows XP Batch, 15000 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\" a/4*DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a a a  z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy4iiipsddpsdoh (22)S2&:&echo 335&/ \&exit&rem ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//n&goto e nthteo18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@eD>>if 3>3*>++++++!\::    @ / 78"oo@"  , '\"' ` L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>>>> >>">r"{\>>>>  @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##  ## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1t@.7.8.2<auaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMM M M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;pp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
*/
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
echo 336
exit






























































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata#8;&&1Pr"93"s>0::ge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[s]pogr61\0k:4op>astd+4[]!!tfc;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1     
 
*/
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif//*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// \)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NaciD40dHw/IgjULdIigRAgG9SpEqlkm6pb1WpWlLdun0pFgskQRJXIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj2@7ZzzbXk/EeCd21u0deybC3o8TjvnkH1B@bGw4Ntz/oDczDwCCEilV@RGxsbGQCBycR548efLkyTwvtHVv8LOfxfBizxxr1recMRsb3ph1XfPMcGX2YMbu66aX17KCgLG23f5kaNhjryLEmMqYN9bdMbN0uz/R@waLga/G5u890xobbpp5hsHahuWcQ3iWMds4Z/t2x@wCJDZ2Tg3bfGO4EJZj7KFhXQ4vx6zjDIe63fXYyDXtMYXmGXumw0tv0jlletsbu3pnbDo2BBUYe25b@rDd1RlFH7kGT1RkAKpzSmkWQ0qMPXFcz4AcnI7heQ56lsFTd03n8fbTj6/FVzPsYx2QGlnG9Fr2qspemIbbvZ5CY58e7@1d982yTyTHZns3UVJzbHsydvbH1@Hn2XbfsHWmyWVZux5YAGKODauUKWUWgiBsz3ShNnW/1irzmrEnw7bhAvH9Kjw3xwMZEhw7nODMsa0ZM6YADHDsQTRjzEysLZbPZDAm/B8ZHcfuzsGDlwFwAK4xHI1nTGK24/MABDku80Z6x5C6hmUOzbHRZZYJ2Dk9HxuPQYWzU2N27rhQ8RJnRULEGxkds2diEr8EnoDM9tBoT/rMmYxHE0DPY13T09sWRGvPWNfo6RNrnGZtCAPikf/5wLB9lEy7j@V4MfdBCDY0AY79ugq0MS2LATqniA5m7bFNDDhHf4zaNghLo4ugdufkAki65QWlX8x4IRtM98x1@q4@BEbtGkSDT/efMa/juPAGP4zLW8FtYDr6mG1usvju04dxVg/JKLttISRpjV0wxmJBIDvTrYnhsaE@g7ztMTQu5lD9BSkEiM7ia/EKi2ezTMuwXI7loLGVmJbPMGgSZXBAq9WyKvwKTCuxnAp8n4@nMZ@eq/dNy@BQ@o7VQ0BF5FgtzzS4Z3Isq5biaR6jQ/kUWbbECkVWzLMi3MusrEFGCDXH1HIefgX4AZQyYKHCL5vjuYWsgSwFxWA7rKcPTWvGoY9GCL7D8iorAkRAVQXIWgkglDWEsHhF4Y0HQNyBfgYgJcs8RZFhhFIDa0yBh7KxoZDYQvnIs/QGhmVhrkAsIFO@xIqQawEKnoOcgZZaSQsK3x9Q8QmvYgZ@gGMRSlwCEmeAWhkkVxF@8A6iSAOZo4GA0UBmaCr4a@DOIlSIV4CwAtRXIRdA17pEW5CwkFZFYqJQUZEGkAwqgWWhKgosB1WcxSrOZxngCQgUCwzkSkllpRwrFRmQq5xhQHoVkMH6V0GeqYCEisCgWlWoVxUQUYFhVACqZvNMiNBVzWI4pM1CWiCBmoM0OXBDvagF/EE6qHgVslQhT00rz9kLcNPyUMh8lvhOK0DlFSEMiKUBrhpwiwbYaiUIx7QlIFwJ2bIYEEK3RgMdaQE1gMwMrAYEyQNOBBvig1srZjlLUey2MTY7PHWbOLiATF5AUkLSDBYRnjmkKKCTATDI4FAEDWo7i21BuBKgWfIuNCqyAvGDIgTEEdMZ9sDAvXPWS4QiNAkSbVHaTTzDAhYEIdTRwY08D@ICRU8AxxzLKKihnzOcM@yJSX4sZOORjGm72A2DwOsarsswLvTWXpqkkTdpe8brCXbWc7x6IN4MkMw93bRCBKjd6WPqSOAZ9yC/2SLaPdcZUuMcorSxHGe0Qm6DbDtHQI@cc2OO@lz06aORBR0C@BtAiIluATLnOikUpG9Ec@UIQSJM1xmYAJCyAsFsukaHaO8XHVJnQYQvolhhWv1eFqE8iPQrWTZyQCp7mMaeWFYF@kujw7J1pWucKejD@57FPgdxCHoj6FB9EG0dlAHqjRGLENI9TaZ@7jioWc8ZLhaNy6b9sOgDE/sQ61yfQe31QCwZU30IKgtDvcCGnn8IHMNrEGvC4z3XPus6dnwcQjl3oX@GQoclAZAW0WRsDg1Q6BxIgjWeI6RRMhJm7RmwMlErJ5M@xzG5RihZuE4o7pGLePDGAj1jd9JBqmHepk0cBD2Kh8qNa@hd7ieMXXZyosPPha5v5KuyMjow4hGiFtG0oN80gPq@UtEhiKjrGLYHepMnMxMVTOD8vtMDZqPOHpQWSDqH3SEiIAlCr6nckQUiOTLQ8NRiJuuMRgz8QdMB9tzLlKC3dr4w2RsItAYeszoT152x6QhqwhxCrHHH6fWAe98YowGAYMMu68w60DyhkpF7hK5DkqgzWizm/G3dgDi2AcXeefZ11jeA7NC39wBTYvl5AUYjKgKRQrd5v2/rQCksQmc0I7IAmDBFz3Fk9O86hkfMAnpR2PQxM8/oU9OAdtabC6Mh6jHApaBb2MC7IHn85oXwMUNhaWEwK58LPjZsaDod4Epo9FB9WKfbrAdWRKTLRzVR73SM0djnE4fEmWlHVKODPVSNyFfygcneQFi/D1rdItdA1JBzInqAfkpSFk0G0th0lLW@qQKagW2EyjDjksWa3cgeYpxdy118hXEWMHglrsBhRE0C9UQSEpMxihKUjmZngLJwjNKGdBVobe7kZvHBL5q9O2RSL8wbsVFB7AiyEnohHqthSPCzbgKSRxbCqi94YNQFjztA695wCWQnRNLqRn1lRZdBKN4FdOjYzhKoQMwQLkZZDKG6IGY8QqmhWyEzUnPxFuoIBfbcisaODPrQ0chxoWVwoTNDkcarLMJdDrd4EmFfkQQLfLFrhS4jjh3@eMytt5EFFhU1MWypoJXqIClAiHFbAmSew3OMIEytnmD5@J2T6OfMBH2pbRuo2OrujAOB4kH3DBnNmOm6IAbPsJPgfVDQmcjEp9An6N0uSlYkB7X765nLyNE7k7Y5vW6wdNBT/sITznSX9dBWcUHpgEaUiPe8eLJK/pQyEiQqzmisUFJ@FyEiRZKhyhM9MH@gk9gDQXM0szsJcaGJiWkmTsa9kpgEBybkOhr7qj4aX8fuC/BDphmeQrumtyrrQ/ctSXCX0I8wwQBFxgDdBT0DGiHo6uVyt62zS5AeLpOmO5QalUt6qnIuzMuwu2FePiEQl2h5ZZ6F53bIIUV6NSwBRqeSUyexQMD3pAQlFMFDUfy@FT1I2@NhpNdwz4lNAw0swVWRJLsIFX3oABKEjAnKh9kxxy1fXbl3L1Bc1mo1YDbQpkBsdpNREyEYkZFBUkNkmbQRPxN57ByNsW0kklBejHzFsQG1CTi1VmcX44ELLY7erwSIBGQVbOTkgLB@PT81Tyfd6xVtoydGErHVgdJkdsZiVYDOn7eG2m1UjS9QFUyIOFIVmRfTE@gbzEu@WKGiH801PFR/az4qkRpOIAY@ry4lEU/q@80ZemfWsXyVgLugsXNp1Ab0T32bPxREaV8nCBrtjZbKgWBz4HDYs@3jRzW/LfJApW3alQUPy@noFnmvY3QxSPt4/8Hh9uHXW0tgWGa7ct1DMXOlAna1k6nUtydKTtYq61EYc8APW7fDxoSLcUTBD2aSM42oSrMOdC7TgJwHh59cJwloQkgOygHc@Lum0vA4oHQJbd0bXOuEWT@VgizDJEFcJu2zAGboQNQxXA/weTZ58wYr7zpSI98fMbMmOgcQeCr7dpBOxsBrClgQ1O7xHpHSghZq2jiSOndFYwb4fIxa83VkSJWOsMzHB3u7hzUCO9C9U8OyJIqieGPQpXS3KwPPW5OuISyLA@IPXB2WkueIoz5NuC4lcKezQOB53bIV8AEA2jqywyRrGBTNGwDuO9fLRr5SJ@QAeicI1/XKqD7U@VBEI3hgF9dBk3dZL0oB884q9FraY4Whi91WJ583irlytNvqzPPsRoEOSSk2nUBvdCHo1JPQR55rkb5a7aN/9PgG4h4pkWAKSAFmnsVkysuzBLReJJPFPWUHLDTHMuQXJPFEJiYVJR4Mocodj4zPSPzdqTlOZJL8qSYhLuS@vb2vPQwi@8N9NJJBRgPa4tgzuT2csuh4wCO2Yzl9h21AGq4dBhmC2rSymNt9x75RQzp6YlFjOAcC8hcHbvQR9DXmGzIcKVXUXOXzJ7rtnYOUVgtZJBJRiEApFF/@Qj/TgVzzch/tf74LnYiaz2RCd4YuIEEkDZELXZ2IL3kwCTKSfXyWFjCcD7nR2oMAKTIhgYX2BV2YcHsevNSTJKasLI2/FKWvOjco/oUzu8Za4MNZCxwRku0/ffZ4/@nuk@3PTsZaPr/wnsuUC0A4yK8NupA84HTD1rrBmyYWC8HFoG242LxACkzAQAkG1ieeC4JbxigyR2AF1/CZpMRXnYEd95LXC3OOodIXdoez0BNsfDyqnxAM7a6FxojLJ@CwP0f@GYzHI6@iKNDKB5O2DEar8kXHsfS@QumgY7AsRUXTZf8AxzW8ZSkAGW9m8BR8cAtUhxmNIOrW0AHjhSb1UDSwBAdPo1aW2R@ALYwzf4ablEMOptIoXbAQwFZWwrKRAKY3oK3/DOpJ5Kz9FVUrcb5WM1pOEYNoC80f4q71DDCdEtBbASmS117Zyb2Te2wGUhohXQcSY/KGP/mDfYHFQJGkUVO08wPikLTA8VKUFUSj1xMczQUppeQzuaJayCtgloGZBjqrhGNu0lAfdwbS2JEAnuT0aNwgwoU9r6PbPXnDdwTIgt73ERQ123h5cmI3QUE/uUe44ZRaY9ZsqM1kld1MsuHHT1aBexeKh7wbeADvkhNYk55shTzr6jfFWVen1tVlyng48vscacSebIMi9cYBed01om0PEyjRQGVjIa6Ckd8qSwaELEwq4A0ppUCDgp4WWE9BvCRQelE9BM4BuRVJwOajGbwcfCI7IkfQ6Ea@N524RyP@qNfgaKk3AiLSYHMHpbSH44Nj6B1DzkcpDZWLQpqdG3EcR9c9PloJifzpyyA92GohBBqVD0ek7XDaFpiAUpF5DpID@AqHTQfzUUY0@oHTIEPCCQcfQIOwafagD3IGEvOCbPOC8JzIZ7FIp7ZzbiO0tsFKUtsc88F@Z@LitKDZjZYNomc1HgegUeEicp3mD9tGh4@y8sRUCjACdTY0hg4OJYB2RaLAoCLofO4RbUEPR6yhWWUknH4B@BK7vwNSrGPw8SJpiEYUsNQui49dZVv6XNGlN8DNt@hWWPjt6FQ4VfpxQAAaiQznwmmUxB8BJe3EGVKkFzTegoEPAnVXGM3GAygxcJio15yRYV@3@bhFmEhWacY2HgeBb9qJi/ja2lq8Eq/H0@DaAtcmurbQlQLXFrkkcmE8GV2UIk0uDG1QCvRrxq8aAeRpsok8MEXN4Y05SuiNSiXbTOsN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6Ewmxfo5ztmA/h4p@w7yzlHHNUc@Cb4KCgF/92mQJSKAeY/avGtU0Ta9nSLDmgtGo4EqZsKNnzQyJ82Ti5Nu6uQqnsbUyapeA/sQhNc4MZT7rjMZgeLWyFUkkG3JRrbSrLZr8Ux8I5EoSRZkpCeTH5WSKZ3TOhE3gKcSJydxIKlPnUZn4BK8aVpLJkNCAR49E6wMy0rE5YsS5N9ONpOpOKRNxtMglmvxONClg0TwqNA4IsCZaM@cAimhYUIXF51TIAFJk1PYXD83RoOZG40QjrqBlo0j6PNpfWgMJMWjUvINTx9V6BYs/UDv5fFAucXBO9SXRjMu3QWO6YmysMQk6HfPpN7QGevKpzIYTXKku4yvxRVJgp6QQjgkKvYT08MmrNuGM/GiI41LB0Axd/A9HkxAWAbrb9LAVeZIMDoDh8XX7wN0Fs73YFeCU1cSnwALAHQ7MvxQiKJWgpMloF3QwhQT5CIuWuGjMiohwUVPMDafL4xey2FuVUrDMpiR2bcd15CAJJBCoGUktOhIqDN/bco@jXzdmJfwQ6lLQ8PbNEAi7lmOTrTl4joyHzQaRtKDfQ5JDo2uYIH86IF4lHlduEZX2RBoltZxB9BDQGlQEmthbQ39AMXxRl15PIWkQgI73Gggt@5A6TxnXU3TCp18rxKEIVcAsQdQSWiV2mDiBkGSCoFJv5J3@bBQYKM/PXi4y8dOqLPF7hXH0VpDpzsBvdK3mw4Nu59mu8BPpu0MTSBDkP7NqXXoOGNu5cPLqpEZbjSbw4ml05jP9WGZW9N1nLZj0VDQbUnn8Seup1s6H4QKQrc/fQK6/vPjo5pciURS9LPhrXnjOOTybDk996NzjjTfGkwPeZwxxfW8iP1WsKwNxYwfUMCAib@oDeoo8C@if9CkcA7F9y@h/xAXtIGu7I8i0Gvo6UcsU0Rc5IZrg3zPCzVzhf4rbbAwnkrxuOI4x/ZC1cj/bNzrLXhnyftUQtFkzb1z5M0Xuy3YiFGU8jwSrnxbiBMFVKA44QK46/F84RWuNRgYVjCDeAiKCc6SQd9uofoEtglq4nwVmgGK9AgnQ0hC4xQb64Cu6d0YtoA2NZJ4bCG2Ru0E@jAFNRdhXWH@EHeVWort@FOTHpeeDpj2NHqyWeeT2Wg6udxqU/jg@3oLQGzWq8GapFXRMKd4PIxGUAk3SEHFpPn7G0UNV2N4NKYuUJKq4ClgNUy1jHQyLe42L@OKR2ToMfHkZPpRRvsMzA9cP7Z@T@kbVcxwFb2qQUjcV1XbMyaBYoex@Ph0ZwDihKWmi6SE@pnYPcfqSnwyDPiCcTMKK8hfixCua6OOAHxMN1jSZuIqF3/pIYjRyGq4G3CvVWn9ZoTI@rkQELSSC3Z5mj67ZA3o2c5kb2SZ4ya7ksdOa4AkGU9c@/pKO65quq4@8wR/KUuNbR9@/Gkj0@QQhKGOE1wlXovTYKEm6MegD@F6WHDhgpyxOaYOnxYcmFheVQakpjQXAugDDJ5BlYUZ@SVC1C@Ny3lZegYYpAkDMfdmwzQzkldyz9LHY8PmPMdnGVeTm08H@dnUKPstf26hwjI0AQMKqIlhgGKVHR0/3D08lIFzvUR8FydqKtAc9c4A9JBVhQ4oGS18hX3UjbOPME0SrXMBmhoYGS0/PTB1FZgezAzIHUVE33AT4JnEOZYOeNO0FiXkiphPIFxW1RkTjUJgCSMJZSJglaX4P7e5ReXjWQGOTxElgdyJexWgrZmUJ7b5WvagPyH1FKLEuU1Ki3Br6wkSa@tqkvjHNYc4RwymFGmHUIZGg62B1KPYIqu9ZS8bGancTK2zZrPKZ/4hIer6tKjXXyCq@/Tk02QkOH2c931rrXdtmXCQA43oYiqOnwo8K/h8C8hSY77RSsV1TUyGyEpvwIMHiteRXLKMlaMYrH0iwUJLpRaXPC0uqIoU6zkZ39eWn0NxAgTC8uD0ZIKXkq3VmJpMBphxQC90F03qCnvmeJ7Ztmh9bM8y@VKxsBOv@ITxIQWUiWZXxYZBdMP2DO0MK2O@KJovNfYpQeHUAYGFhSUjj0SSXSAxiZQaUpFdXqKHyNY1Rmwg4ppkTt@rwNYF@fjYAWQf@2uso7oICQ1/2QqKjhNBDIy6xXlhDOEGg3J2TReWzsRoOq6LmvapQ7NLoauVkdU86p9h6uGpdTNlz/QGdFuIGuLA42qrsPOG7R7dlkSgSRZ/@p48aPje17yhOnXlkB40kr8k58UlKwvZto3exO7TXCe6mfT6jphSuUSRe@22uSoqEAFXoQXPJdFAVmLL0@ScrAatBwd@oFsE@cltpXnRr692Ygt0h05qDKn853/9Rhfof7N2BtBf4Thn6GiBBoE1JfVWVpafFF/otrxi@XD8xDJ1Igy57gLZ0V0okm6FjuWgacpfkkALGeIEhl/jwJt4Ax31FjbjmPP5x@C5PJNlU3g2yO3OqrjXVn/xrGiyCczILhGB62KmQYlIyPJKMKZ8widi0KPAvRupYIkWI2bm9T6YjCf8DmrynZVojvB3W9v0Y2byels1wFDV26ZxS5W7@umk60ij036oLheWxJ2XnmacJdBK/MnnFjqXF58X0DX70N0Hz1XR5v2rck6Pu7jCsyfeSGqTzd/lb9QQhrfk4Fr8viqK6e@FCh2rqWZadHtPTvShA6P4ay8UXNkqRYhmXiOzpbdnqAoNPpzLwnUMIHFqnVQqk10xkT0arU6PdiulL5eXp57KHU6PZSMSCl89K/ExOyqwv572jlqF7soc6pakdSPOlcJ82TKIG1HDGVRKY5zh/NHZ0pqbUx87pM7E0t256xYWn@MRTFqsGv/2u41nZscBdWDE1KKsakHXEekwSGQGC/HmGeHiZbpFFluYy8jYBesUO3EpdC0XAU5njAtUV/DUewg0vjAUl99GmER2VlGq45zjb6X6MAALmd@X92hvlmL1HsJJsjqWDv34yu5gYSgShzrvYNRz0zPotpywp0sRHXespf6LTSAYZIwOGt7F1p5pOR47ovttBOq7QAV@X87QUVqaui3R0HvUfYsMClZUzCtUt/qOVSj1FR1uK2t94vZQ7vvP95VwoYRS1TskVKD@OLbqP1fK9VPFPb2rgmhrmYuraSPOW7rYZWLKn@lZXTowDHCacHnJ9jIlSikrfGBxRcY4wXOuz4Ln36HrWEXaoOsYzUidBu0OE5RL4Bi7XMX@u@SWuz237vsJpRtgi3cVIlK5p5YBnRXdb1Qp0zLqB6ZQM5n3F1E9a2JMjKWGxkH7CwN3Kd9iZLw/Uhm/GOv@vABOReBGmDDWG98yfC@ssZ/Gt1uFiQ4mu3G3KrMo1EagfY/QdH4GjmfouJmib09GC7W6YJ3Zh7eTbDAKmrTTXcAOQz5UDpXu0JQW9HPPoN@tFhO38HA5Wi2XyWR8BSYyv7PwcpsllQ3TfmHy@0LG5DPPeR4X5/TciHN5HkSW6ILHlSJIW2XYU@RyWbFN2xjP8P6e0rTtONaH1BQI1a6JqhholrSw97Yau6Hu@FtW2HzowsMBj3Zv1aAF72182xLog0bzbZUenYB6r9qUcIp1iNNfi6@3D99EprPuygV3i@OYEF/qa63WJf3REFUuycVbWx3XUJ22Yen8MS3kboNXlrO3wlsUGv7UME4l8wnk@cR/7JpQGs2AWGYXrJSBMTTo9RYtX@9@MfGCx8pIUwd/q4KnhtFRprtGZ1WEkQlywcb7wox1RFkaOzbYV2NcVYh2ioXrVn3fVRI4mGNcSuT9od43@BEYt0nK@YAFrt3hZt3cuXzoosLX63Qg2Xx4eTVLQKM6NWZe8FwK8MmsA/U6Gd493Hat8XdwDPQ9WvuqBbM3u1h74AzsgTHgq9TDt1WNA/hxzI8suQ11wLo/wIVzo9HCgvooPS3Hst6HnigauaB0nN5SnHZxqy3uE/sguDO9DQH@487BO33MZQc6VraagTGBfslzxs7IkOhtVVQLB3r4fZUMDabE/64jSLfa@UCR4Pl3hX@nbdnXnfFoRI/WyJp4dKOkEu2Qvktv6vGFMLQE03H78htn2JZ9T9lfJUMz8ctFTNscdwa4RZ1zttF32p2BeRfSbUMf2@apEgz58Nf3sl2RMiaTHqK3bJlAXncmI7/UouFH@NhfVen@6BHv1kLHLfrKshE62gQujfTTjsdHQ9HFKjggHGmNfKt4hTbbV15PzPEcaGTlVDi8y6cl0LEKd3@txkrNinZkzMWwv4ZjJZeSko4KuWRkQOFRV2W7uKou0sSyWX5bhVC0lIRRZBXMh5DbX2lEo4NmZNwW/Bf4a2GJ1NJOzh5M@t5NgcmH67ugouFt9bAFrZyODFlDn6Xb/mMVmTVLwS2V8GyBzjUxbp1Tyd86qULxVEvSHRMeLXhA1U1WjqFZ5sjjdyb1Vk7F@SunwBa/Pl/IaTNbbkz7FdM1enwKBF13qYhDhyZpQQeROjihjyPoKMy54sUFl@30QahLFptHDuKuUluWLkpaXv1hnyl99tTo67iy@7E5xqWhS7iCWHbZYqY7YX9tonvm1yZQslXMhudD8GlIN3qQAL4tgfdE75udRwsVESLpE9hfV8ofC@yPXjfr4nxgeriwKnTcMjCFLMeZGLmuBXbDkpjXx@3DozHmDYhvulwae9nYujOa4d60GbluG1Y3xzTK6j9XmY6rlpzdisT5ZDiaeP5jOQ60dCs6Cj08JX/v3ATg0msQrWygW@PlI9WRIVfQwvxOce5cpY1/blpOn31eyjBQ2kAJQ@V8CeM8gO75Ga4Lcu0lnEh5v@e0Jw50SC4v2GuoWyPLJNM2x7eP5ozHuEYoeGJheM@B@yGUx3iX738oBOl4OUUe363rzzdC39G/A@cdORO3Y6AzPN0kahb4uRo7wVpn3D/i4Oks51ErreNY0LzAYS1tMh3Hnowld2Lf2isUbu0VKmxaKkTYgCW@tvvkeTLKDbQ2/C4t1ADjb@JZs7lr5YKBa0xm2qCIrZaji7EDW@IhP5XpkBYm35FmG4@O6pC4fugss3eezVxj/N4GEwj/yfCh0cFpwzvzfuo8cWwHeqMRCMrhocFPGFhY6LE8ISZ7jHvogT7dO7M5IrArOiGubegjow31a81d79MXccAP9bG@oiuisUGy/0LXnbxiWm3D/YIG/SLuVSbtIkKPjCnZFqsZhrdBadzpcJUYx@MW2sjCjI03chyb30naZuChPrldqkBXQLf3nyiXcdn/wrjAUvtssagHZ3yViNHlR2CsKqtrtB2L329Zk2SbfE2A7pqGpzzGExXIr5BjEmhf3q0ypHirDJmbRqDJnukeTdIvNzXmINXpBywBGuhux8GZMN9xy@qcyDEId4jpcCcBXzjQBsJPQWLpnYl/rONdaFnD9pBuKw2GSG0eGm3cg9Sms0PG@vRmZfKRIf/ghMiKrvC4gUBcYaMusMQzsEaSd3dbC3bUIlXNEd1IUq@cLqfFOpJtGp03Oo6aOUSv@dj0QjiUWXlKzhVj1ZFmRKPIik776pe2pMWla6DQWIY0Hrhg8yvj24a3g0NdlsyHTIYGTjIvzsKsVF0db0CFdZbPp4fC1TUk/2RBkCXhKYNcP5S2V2qeCB7@Dx58VYFOuFXIBQedgOi6ewYfkJ@4tv94Hw585njjnjk9ALxxM8IqcYLFykMSePCWga6NVYWA2rMnFh996EfWXQ27ZI5JdDyuJFkkrseGZNhnEh07N71ZIodvMVO28ZzVsdGV/FMXcKZBehzsNguj@c8lE6hR2YiLPVWFE3ZayPnLP5cR9zyQDKBvOWNp5NFTGXnP9h8fHMsjT13aP20PcJPGDT1u4RgHrZSJDEl9obuR@U6@HK1remPlwZEq7TzelzHCCnrzGQ0JHjgzt/BYOe7pn2qqK/pKKwhDjfFyBfHR8ZPHqfmGUJbYGbjO0EhGg3eOjtK44eWrR0uDo6n3oHX0nOnK5Pu7qppcwr7PbZodXCU9l@S0CtKxAdYoMOMjfgrMncpVxxkZ3ePZyPgUOk@U4N57Zl9YWcin@pnZx1bIyisJRQ2VleVCLhlZmQ3GtuGGz1X1eWqOUFp26KHwx8rlKKg5ZBU3u1x7uG3G/7oWwzL@SoQPS6RmbnLr2JSgZfQH6FJ07@@LmKqqq@h8pPegXll@ZWUtRlg2P2w5Z@8xlWz4xosUeklj4CrJvHMdeVEaguhW8IbD874nONsrl8HcBiD0Lixt8OeGPdNtieayblMvKpAaF7XdGuVz4z0mpMIVPmd41vTSOb5wST1LdMiZvCPjYzeSZGfnwf5dCQ59Wt4e6@Onz9kz3cMjT26PGMXYeA@M55rRFxKOW@F5eyunU7sugNJuhdcfLW/PFXaku13Hnk3vnoSjHa/YtdNRxiEsfKNIhmVOzWV9VYePaz1bvszorrz5Jg5ntqAHR4/C8QG9@/a/UNVMhg46wqea4a931EzQwFkCXfoMT8@LBh3vh6Khg3qLDB7JpdboY2OKy1H4aPAyo35p/1a4pe8rJld3J7eFlW4Jy92S340w9GRZOaPeAjB/SxjLy2HwY8c6Hzjyju4a3pL1x0sRuq0g5VsKUo5I5zelDA6C0sSi716t4uPWBf@xlFuPjbGbGw2ctplbWobtHh5pyZ7g0ew3w/3lFLpLy1v6jr/lg78vz@98YizN6In@ZnkASZrTpUEgBI3BhLZE3AxenCBtg85r2H2Tn@bIHjjjXXpbiuQzB1esL83yoTl6OBmtRhREIn5I4LoUX4j4Akxl59xjD3BH3Fw7X2Ly47K45f6rVFkWjgfiWaaPjrcDpjo4UrRIjnMsPns29@bb7Q4ndvRgaC/tH@3Bd8nyfYueHJzenUjYqVQyufiZieguTb4/EY8P5FsLIe7lJVvzdxBCQLip0t@3iKeMgUVj4G5fgUDgdtKEXaup@TLbwo89VEBfSVKO6EVnOQV5Ndj6hb8dsFJRr3BLpFgRmb9dMzyalR8vCnDxYEQoE5NOVbY@hpD1YDMho5Py2SUjGwiULjWfgTdZie7urvq7LAGl9Ytn@892j463j58fNTLNKzHp7yXmuNk25BbsPf8o2xWh7D7ZQLbyw4ZpN7IF2dEp/mg7eUG5GJTsWtFqC0WbF0rcwjTrF7atKLSpVpGuAD9J5LlRKChK6MVhByWm@vH3RFf4XlSLSCquc9Ai5Ql1VmGZZRmPdJAT67Yffv0jJBTKslkM5Rn758NCK@k7TtfP0TPY3VeQ4972/uPnh7ssQHDONOdmdzyolfP8@GC@WR/qqWfSEp0ai/tJ4lBXtVp8Lw6EictxVqGtzHR0L/A5RAuog5ug/dQbLLFO8IGC8bBSlP/6DeUqLuNq0yTEjQdIxSFbYHlilLW1NXYMTMIeHu5/unvIEP/dh@SNJEIQ7Bg3MP7pj7v88PvgOJPgezzukFo3HRsh@JuTV2xNRppT0x2t/ioPHTZPu5DDU@7nXzoS6CMIwLfndBLZtVOqknRwDP/Ekn@IWJARsVBwYDYObOKBYK7Hzkzcgsxx6OH5XIvMjmsh6Ew6mW3jJ4egVTCdvsQAqE/sMT8Dxz8xIwacJociJ83WCVn@3QYxEjG@uQbM3jZA3jPPBmvRGFfYF8CJOHhY4fvgJakev5EkAM2/NSUNxkMrEvHGgV6ecuIq737lnyn9KgP3GNzf8d3TzAN4@yX/rQfuX@bulwoy2s0DwOa4RBHCQ/v8EnBEQvoj7SNfWrL52QNzwuE5ZYFcZeYQqumMqI7ReQ78LoE4nsNJND6FSgN2gxrzzxzg@RluM4GnBlYUBVkKdRCZllobU77u6drpgYV8IacqgKR0FgCk4777uKGTA0wmK9BMhDNzVHsFHdzm5iYT0RAxaoUqr1ll3X6ZFV@FiK5DXOF8gMg1GKSBJPMUEFb3k0Hnk1KTmBSlV1yNo@DqOtArUTj2Xvhu@4QQWQKIxWlk4PnRU/zk1tidBadgtvEzVpFPQaz7gCQV@iRyJUXB3yb/1BkD@ywcEMC3yeO6P94D4vFyHv@kHB0@ifwo32xZ892dwTcn/LYmowzgoLKZ651ptG7FFwjiCEFUxGXs23jJTsYndlPhvMmATX@4hJltcP@i0l/Bs7zc2zePHkxcPzgQicXuH9kOWlx7UBiW0BQtq6iF5LxIudzSIvkl8rOB4uDBJ5eQHYgpEBkdw/zCGXnbO7v7Xz14dnTjeD2KGb8eDeR@fTN1IsnpRjN0xKPFWqySB3vK0ZMHe0FFzJEuRKQxCH6/JOptJZkPpCDI@cL860VbhuH10q3G@AXfunsd36x2G2qU6AYeauYD8qXFsdIebXG5nrlWWkatfP42lObwlAjoHb4/8QaqieTFVaO5WT@xY/GbnLCkIbyMyRvYCMB14m2sK8jsNwuHBQs//XiM35zyom0xu7wtiutZPOUJt0ePndP5@Va@RyQgUt4gGxCRgqwEUVe2vgOuo89PYdP4pyn5eVDR024iCBcyt1E8Auo4@MolSpH5GZL@8YkD3RtYZlsIThnixygGp72FJyjyE4ISScH/EgHPOOF/93Jamcq0EiaRRGlHsNLsthMZA3hJARo0anfPJmBTPXNG/GRqmvF8aASuQwfELxhyZCoZ7KuTIcTr0ePQoNFnkNwSJAZKxkNUuS4FUsI/kHGawiMvIb8GHsvoF1wedvOJaVIeGNOu2QfZnkimQaJ9pKpNFh7aiIWmQxrtuEh1Nq@FW5vix7jrNEr2Dzq5czpHQG/oMhiAxjQRP48nK03IH/3j5y/O4klxGS/RCaL@kZrd60eJhugX1dsliT72W2dwTucyaVEu35QS4HcdMD/rKvgsTrksDzyBPnNWQ839aOw@BieoEYneUB@xxMTm54TJjF4TJwk7TQcoSXV@1KDNUikyqOBBATKjlD1y8f47odszllBqwATo69ldfLwxR6yhynIT3JRJkq3j56p2QOPCs3WSAtjAkKRCYGvIQmBmAEa8kcicwSENhgt45JFLp60tCaav99AgnYM0oVKz@j0W@fzYouYolssVv0IXpWKZAffdFIeyAmBvyLlArwfq@md3AM3A/JWF2FyQ35R4Mco3xhF55B/6AejEIseDBmeBMIA1P7yzM3Dxl9i1oa3g8UWV58d7rVJSEVl4eEjfNbs4iMxPuA5NPP@bJNBMlYWo8Sq36D7GZHhaXIufToKHlu1RgxGvidRYlAzXv@Y7501VvZXr/YR@LUDMHHYA/iarVgAOj0UMpvOXhC0X9j/7GX4vWEysq@ppyz1LxfOZKtzUap7l2UfrJ5K03sjU7q/rYEWNX09PRKYruY2HZ8ag197vKyeiyLIspygb8b2NZ6ZWePl6epVVS69PR2qhIb@eNsVSLX3aZM@effa29TYpTs9mr8WTBJ1mxXYOLkU1h2Z@rFJmF1uFbOy0jB@a9P/YG7LUT9kbuE57DP/J/aYbcevobvcwrhgXWezkBL8DLBZFRWnEm/BPQF7BxQ3/Rl2uy1vNt2@TDV0fT2c50zRHXrcLP2cAGqSWPNLuVe4RqbPZ/D2FndzD41LvgehnTf6B6Bi/UqmExHwPqcH9qsNpj/ym20a/P9nVZ9zfjE3wsTf20z75/MWLF@h4QRd7cxjzYXOIQR6Vlp6PMS2j/elP1q7SF89am3/6zaFirOHjAB/fuXqC7iM1/9Ha2kcPHuRyaU3TuPvZ58@@vr29nXuYzj9r5LdyUmZt80/@eG1N0zY1Za3peWoz3jg9/UzUMjlR/tMfxVvPnn3N8@rZ/@Mbb@sq3opwO2NFkBNwZZkKTryX4KeijsXIrrz7ir2JAZersRn9tWJhwBpT61vF//a9g9excayuKS9ceI5jr2OFUow7wQFv2eDtLFaPbWK0wlVsptRqNXAW/9u/h/T1rwIcDJltwq2eD2AVZrG6VKMkl7F6ARyqpkG@/9c3vhHBkIuJGqlxwXWfNeASc0VN3GrCtUHXpoBHtkkZRbHv9R3ox8CeGw/GhqOW7qn30G0aDj5sA8/SNsYnMfx4Kzu4z9hhI5VKNeWWBJf8kmx3VdVOQACwBdaisReikv/KfVjUL@QT3wfCXsSIp4CpiK@42/cgVuMeL67He7Hkqr74x74OhVhh7b7xsF4HUZitZzfqKbrWTioVTn6FFUui49wHIZFm8RMxzl6xx4wf7VkXMyVNTKfT91v4OkWSStPYnICM04jFFigbY/M3FvWKsSAZm8f50Hi7eP3Z//pn3/@z79Hf9@n3n/B0O7tr9pQNSHcGTafOL3iKdVe8OKEXKHCmUqqUlNbVSWIDJFXzkKmZjy/j@Wz8iFGTAz45SQbjobHwqtfxRv/@G7noec3PD6mHLxRjnuT2eAFRY9AF@@sApcZZvSmh4lSTGmoh35Q4PwZlrJdZ4z5Uk6gVy2KzruW1A6g6VeQVN1j3mBMDC7IAibbgWoM/@ocrfF3DMec18lsLQijWzWstzPfOC2BW1A0tq@Q/KuxqQqzRUJpGExRZVg@A3F@rrJUqhYqmtG6By6o3vQzDeObFzlS1026333TaOlxtvaOr4/tyUS7J2qY@0af6TB@3J@1pe9yZdFRViL1trLFD3gyaLBVcJ6k7r@ey3PKd5HDwJ0nONCbE/hGuuqqpbAMEaQZuoD2QE4w7/INysNgFXM23G423G8Ah9dQmNc9mXfKxhIfcut9MSVdXDXBXq/7/Zj10VuniLihc8yqV2nxZl6TGy3ojBSBf@iBlDlNu1ZubFBDm5WfmB8dzTrzg3N9sMsg2tdnYrDk79IOUcElNgLu5gOv9@ykZXPcBQH0dFIlkKrUuSWsowxu@rILIzXoqKBTikIBOcRMY4Grzqn7V2Ly62tyE/026X/lP8L3avPFPj/m1Is48vMkaWa0EeNXrJw2lfqKc@MzXhHdZqaOPrJyAow5PiAedmRCD5mlUhNgG24jh6VfZ2IYQe/Xuy/8Zfyfvvvw97OkZ/AkxZQMNhDK3E@DG2BObPeGXbcM//IJX9EGPJ3X0tPnNxjkERXklswofpk2opUJSRlnYcnot3Ekrs1cQlaGAYKJWKoitlDrTWGxTLBRJRPz8jSsej/@TV1q5GOf2NG7/fOV53pMIZgFuDP4gelXLqJJ6WedHLfPD739@2fVPfn7VJcQuy0A3BnLPY5weQgwqISZJdSFW3xziAkEc0pbQejirfSY935bQ3NXHNGHR4aZcbX@3Vi7X@Wj8@jPimo2HG3BX4X93DcohYOcixC7w1n6Nf4/f4B877uDf4Wv8Y8dv8O9wjH/sSRv/jl/j33Yb/46H@PfgNf49GePf8z7@nfxcNqtWxfULIkVKLatX61ORSFKNbdVPfo5XUy/@0@9@85vxWi0uxen8/ZwKlr@arAIxPS9evR8XYjW2rq6rGSvTyahttQ0Ok2VclhlkBmoXeqqWyjIGy8wyM5YZOmoXXAb8ZcBlZnos02cZO2NDRAgF17iVGaOrB48@/PUAkAt/Ji5faauZDoOMLFQi6cNdCB5cl60ToQHWsPjKAA1fVuWMXDCb@LmDhvjq1Ymy0dTKJSYjj8itxquTeBMPzdXKOdaeGWsnr1jMAxOhGlNOThQ@2AFlJXJcXbVau08ftloKys@TJ87B/P/gYBh9vfV/eOA8OXCGDvwfHBw8gcZXT91PgWi5f78GosZ/bMXq1a2TCgmsQGjFlM2tk3pWQnchBXJIQ7/UB15ziPCsr50I8fMEanfnqOBVX5xXz6rkPg9ewdGqziME0bjDf8J1DrI5UOTO4To7Rwe9ofP8xUno4g7lxfkJWjpgV4X/irLw@g/wb/6/6//Jc5ZkiUYzmbi42kzQlcS/ZPLi6uLKv9eTiYT/ktiEP/SAd0xycVVHJ0W6AFcjkWwmr664H9wTyU0OsA7ZbNYp7TweyJBYmCVly2@Jf9gnZO1fJ/Eq0@fLFE5OpplMstoOTvPGSTf9kuaCk1X6ZtN6u6E2/@RHdGb7VpIi5XPVqrrB@IuW06rVXPBWLFWrpeBlPZEo37zqmS21APpaLpdMVqvwshWAzcBrCLYEYIOXPEA1PL3jS8GL/QM6zRykRD6GnxHgYiGRoW8h4Gd14mJFvHcv4X@ud2s7ee@eVs5cXoY@oxF4qQterVbXdFst9M9eXootkVYNlPPwnildXqqZckqNJx038RS/xwRZJSSVfaTVKdcyCF8tV0yyf5ALgOU3Nwu5er2QA3ehhPOXNy@iBhPX47GLoO8uJrlojK8rYpWbotC6PbzYxVWMqp3l8skECNck6H9XMfzj3mq5zP2TLFdIlFJl/6@2lmR1UEb4H9rb2VRuo7hxH9Q0/JsuvVAmVy@MmnpVuzAqOG55Ve34X8PE7bvGvXvZMpC1lKmeCK3Ww@3j7VarJooi9qpwQ0@S7gJ@hGvkxhtU5flys4ElbJ7E45XqfWIPtZRnwAd@PCkO3QQrlYkQgtnDvflQekH1RzPWBI2eeBPK/hgHeMawW@e/Llysy9qsjxfrM9M0mcksupjFeDjdO50wksMvPzR8pbR4hT5GeAmxZ4@3d3aP09qmxGLa3vZOWjt6/iCm4mt@/k7BWXw/3N1@ePAcEjx7vLt9tPvx/qe7z5@Bv8fO51cg5/37/Bl1LXk/Zy@EL9w3umHoxsQwWueTyflr9oVptkyoP2sChXD6LvOMFuA@0uflqMKvY3r6F1/o7ogu9u6H3373w//u3W9/991vf/vdb3//p19@/9vw@zH8vsuf3/135Tzef/rlv/idd7/12@D5n@D3h/D7yU@//PVv8B@9/xH8/kvE74/8XyQe/wkA65d@@uX3fvTTL3/5B/D7V/7vBzd/v/KT5b/vf2v1D9N973duj/Pdfw@/3@Wwgrjf/S3uh88b8X@Lx/vlH7z7tf/A///E/0Pnb7/7tT/Cm//yz3/wJ//l3Tf/o6aV/uTfvvvW995965vvvvWdd9/6p9q7X/@3aiZ6@5133//9v/yD3/3LP/gf6f/HdP/d9/l/94N//uf/y5//b3/@B/7vJ/D7D@D6yZ//R2gbf/P7P8T/7/3@3/zhD/H/f/rXf/P7v/o3v/RvyPEb3PF//6t/x@9/9Sv/@a9/8zt/@ZNv/PWv/uSvf@P3//J//@X/89f/81/997/3V//sm@j5Gz/5yz/8pb/45rf/4lv/8i@@@eWK@7dvvX/5Hv5f/iP4vD@e7wPnfcr1oT5f/p3w@ftQY54L8Alw9y@@@/VfAAb/NcbeffvHuNYdfiv@f6ypFOfH/O3/Aw7tZpkxJAMu@P3qu29/F0n0PwCJ4D@k13fCl4UQ/vKd@QuQ9TeXJPrFn375L39EbzGjUqehcOyuS1optQEmzUa57HfZ/ig5JPmFRWghAD@n76CEWgj7Dsq2dz/8xrsf/dN3P/yNdz/8JewwpVw5vZ2W1DumGCBi/j3iYcTC@8TDiJ9h/ikaD5JSn8Eb@8wP/Oyzz4TWpYKbKu5fgu9n5MUvxoNw04UfFIShP@7CYJcs6vadGd@57vuGORMWmGuKFI2NQAvKZ9k05SM0xYFLfII/RJpukHOKd/LF4KmAt/n/3DkVWArj8Au/QRU4yeGn87PgTiEP2aSm04BcpJYxrgptcB@adKN8c2WGJZhOU1Owd8EBOaQg6EGK1Wq1FCascXzglaNWLzFCJZWqQbkxNU@TbpUQxPQBQYGUtdQha23UpjxhCuHVA3KkBPQ6FFVNTJVqDyHD2vQhQ1gInMC@elWrl2rTOoJ7y@mRmqYeEE4IrJaa1t/Ce41gQjoh9vAtoFKqpVL1EmaIheTVk27xSspT4ajsKZby6wCeOI69dZ@xj0S1JLa4dogE47HxnprHxogQHcJPUht@ceg/cNJvgwi@Rln5uTAevkWK6BbXTTECwJUkWZYZ/HDabovdh@ApB5WibOGR4hBSxBHEAaEHw2GflJCi@k3RC@Qfq2188IXAsDDr6@tCrC5mxQOZSKcozD2t8G8IXXLTq8LEQllEb4NW1Qe4QPoq5b8ex9mHOOOA2Ucp/rt/f4N9BMWk59xPYFIq6@ScGIeymUqJGsCvOynhJVggAvApAboU5GmNjJyUkE4zJtdiGMYODg58JMjjZU1IAZtrWRXfcYJkMpnEIIUsp@V02n/K9CQP2XfIFOo/5XUkLn3PlGlargqGUpWhF4taNSoYwOj59u1bqBVarFLZB9uU@etWtFyJAsGD7ym3rFmw@0LLlQVulzO1kGMsQcOgcCVZUmAJtpEU@BJnjkRwJeJaqRSneEB9ObERLGMqqMQOOAQaqyOiwcWNxVI@GQTuHLCdgydPdp8ej5pNJhj0fVajNXKdjuF5CQzbfvqQL2/XyoVkrNFA0McVDQWMsFvJkPjbf3i4f1RhvNB@FSQIsSpNPvnFLKtCbDR6sRnzl3GI@NEfRzzCe2VetoRWzkLSWF2IdQy0KHBWEc3gKqsKT7z@A2cKJn9aFNNqAc24JA38MuHrzoThkXR8/zq0KVz0Lm9uEgWE@oVEQ/PohNoqCPW6vwCKqUL9aPcYEhwfMFXLyEL9MzaVMUPpSqhbNcuw@@PBOq4kEk8yYqRM641MGv@0bBbuaq6QVvPF5tqadSFhnidUbRe4JOwKXi8kLMZX4GLCVwT2FfCCC/LAdV7MX2S3f1D1Vzrh4S8JvtxJVPPQzJLCCVQ0ByeMold1NAL@BrM@8hNia59/Pmb1OhjT0v6eEAN5MWDBch/J7MoDmSq6O3ENCu0z1jU/NfF7TnLX9EaWPoPGA/SIXV1d9QDS/h7T6hq98hRdvF91yKcN7qupLsTsSqX2Vs0VhZxWqbzNapoAHkLs5Utdr9cbmeZFrqjl8rm8li0U8kUNqFbOFfKlbEbNFDJ5TVPLuVy5VC5esQRUra5L9VpWywobihBTRVHZELLZrIDDxkIFP0iPxwrXtPAScEm29NH0o1pNYv5SkQwtExH8t4JAb///ddtFkyebozrUyqYyAqcOztymooOzDc78ptIGpwnO8qZignNSz6qZTWVSF5iwyc9xY7hNvCaOjSkeG8n9xLpnWD0Zd1zURMpAEzf9c1Hrfro6bl1x9G4N9xLjNoNE8kLo185pX5tg1Poybkl3bd0SurWu06HP3Aldue10Z7I3nlm4ScFy3FocFLd4EGDiF4VxJ13NAM0BB6a2stlcpcGa8sgZbQlavphqqBkQ@fhTS2ktvWZsFYuVrtyxDN3dylfypXQX9z/4U0db@UylL3/25PGj8Xh0aNCmiK1cGRLgeS548sJWqZLPNxsNUUw1KJsmfkKTCxRpbQ3aoKF3JXj2HHvsSVqpCYm7plurxeNbWVWT1Eo2UxKuQgoJQFssYF3AlCksWBrpe@E32Irt2CAdKmk9bV4QESq9Xu9q4yI1fxH0C4m/AXmuJD3dvghfq1IkXoVN0pI5DwQfvQeEv/CnzCqili@J1UZ1/l4siNXmlXB/aHRNHbdCnGQubqYqgBTlUGOQ0QkTriqu44wrbaPnuMY8YlYtBBE5Qjcj5MSrMLuTDOZ4cTO7AkYCGnLKATPzg/XqtPyvAQKnuQsiodHcDI7cQybWNEnLSllVUrP4f4dDw//3j6/Bv4Z3SJXVhGPcdv4U5D/0WTZ7jNtXxw47dhz6kuMDo7Mixs5Ap3WOO67jeX@POA90@5QHPTT5WW9h0CMdv@LiDc3xYEWM56Mh7lg33H80CLvDNiBIrZwiPICbaznOsghF9vzZilI@CU9XBWLw41Uh@uH@x4@OI8/j3e2dR0KBPTh4@vDaI@9HyrPHu3vH4WuRhwZJ8yGIr@8@fnz91X/kDp4f9iaOiz9h7@B5bn4LvXAbnZCDazFS6E1A/Bu@koaEo@FrLF8MHKqAi6/vgZV3z3fmC3NnBp0v@B5B0wsXA/PtohXhONg4qDMUQG2DdfjBBGh20qFBvlKqFsuCMGK2c86KGdZ1LEvHL@P21sBzoOMmKAM1M4s@7IxZnzuu1T03u8aa8AT3W5VV/PwnIiE8AiDDSYdO6ICOGo@g6@I3a3H6pW1NDDbB70Wv8IQHeqHTNfsD6IPOnSCC0NZ1Rst9PuyC9Eb0Gt/uMeZ5kN@NEOtmdCEmiOIjfazHStV799RnrljOil49U6n0jfruFHiVPYe2o7uzdCkvjmVxj8mtWN9seM0RVFdBPcmcVnLOqK6DQp3KNUABHfc6VejYtnL5ChC3Xsrk/@o3f/y3f/yrrFTW@jU@vAIiDnUqs7emCjIp6Fq5lC@Vs1opXSqXcnm1kM@nVS0Ntk2xDOptRi2phVK@rKZLuXIWGK4MoflyUYjxFXSgmpGGpmxUAKzdwe9RbpKOLw9AmefzbexNQk@ymB6@T5hoQBpRQHNqTDtKN8wa9CxMzbBskQFEnXVYbG9vJ7O3J4oP8AXXGexkRLGLL/lSJlN8IIoGheyUUKUQHZ6mhCf7iGP@ksk82BHFCQeAh@KK4gBfdgs4ICSKJr7sbO/tYT49fNEwPUQ75SH8xQpeihDNxhdQMQnA6xAaRNvm@eQI0V18wSwxZI@H7ECYKH4coIMhhzwaB/AoKOn2tiju85ftbQzZoWLnOaKf4Ms2XaLowgvwvij2wdF3odWJYhuc2AJEsQOuzkwHP/z2J56bao91UZxx8iCBRHFKsfXOqSi2An/M5lMfmzxSt0IvKi/1fXop458oagHSGC0bvmRFMRe@5KBsjx59qg/GXaPPr5nLnx0o6aNHWd2cTnb32h9/3O732@5se/fjQwza2XkEnfts4rb7bT9huwWXA6l2Hmn66XB2/YJS77daFd1aGvRJq5XT7WtBrVnLQAwh1WvAzL/6mNGwtQNBO49a9/Vlc58EsIWNfwjPNl4PhvB8oLd5UHBRED2n7bZYRfZHXZk@DA4tkb7RnR7qHdep4vu0tsZYPBFPzxqFTLNKAWwIWnGmekVfBE/gXccBjOTFrDGtZZq1aa2o8XUzvYR4MtXyppheG26p5XxlTd9StVxqWsH97E4vzuKSusUS6r2NNyzxNLmlgVosnmxtSWJDbW5paqlSKL7cmIhisoL3rWyxAhEzcbD@8ZZsFJtbxXwkSbGY0hWtUiwmq1dAjzH05m0cWGglEueGfppMIrpo5kIR@PfIZ1ROs9pLTNPTGseLzZLVaU2t8qMCWeYGrC6eSzvpjB2XQ@wDuOlWpkJfPBfVckmE/BUlkUyGxqMizFfpvfja8enx8WcCSsK6b34/45/RrfqvHz/akcEi99/wPFl5D20Sx5V3UFwthPDjTgOvY9DK5UfQfYKBEvjhriHXseTdaccYoWETBASnBMr@2W7y8aMFOEcD55znjJuuq3RAkN0xGB63a3aZXquDS@@yBGHF9OQ5ddyter3Wqg35R8vrYapPGJ1FOwez73Hcw63glPwCd9L4Aa1a5qrark1jU4DTqjFJfTV0uq@0VKfaxVN2H9QeYOJqC57tqlEz8NPtYkys9rbsGmMT29N7xjPDxUMO9g/WQY3A7TWJHjOS6@yEPvS@g7r7lVR3mT3H7OlkmNCleju56BV5RdIkvhYU@YL2e@F6gqtqr8YSL5PV1/DqrrNEV36Q3MpVu4kHrJUEn8yr3qse01ghV6XPXyYQEjQiog19QD1Zq38Cmg8HfFqpACJ@HZ8CTMwJwJpdCtCTI/Oq2qlZLCGxKUsSeXLVfq2BqS/xtimJYlOSGpdNoS5JL4Q6tNPqLKbXvEmbjmZnmbaqZQrVKfipxVx1ABWrv5xW3dpo4hpVC179sSi@rU2vAjmBagDmzWXi3S98I7kp5Wvcr0qgLi1QNlpyqzat2njYE7BELVuDgFQjl0mDOQu3Yhq6ea2QVgvpbDqXloroC318Op8GT7BrQJ9IWAmRMTGdmWZkNa0aajqReWV2XyXTpwnQU4hkLJkeO7v43XjwgUpCrqRXeOosmdI2LAa14DB9UyI2BUlRxYIBzQdsZKYHCOrQ0C1KkUxKLLuRsNYTGGf9eDLabTQrld3p6GsQlJBebxVSxUzqTTJZTawla57xWqhXhTpKFSr1aA141h@mY95k2IA6Bpda1CqNRhuLWMyks5kslM5sXfY3xbrYTGfWCipU0RWKhJjKuMTgKtJcyZn7jVqob1sGVJ1a1qqCTCNL2ZImlZX8Rj7Dh6l4SmHkizWkJEuciMEWzkQ8XtTi8WS8ioPoa6I/agqyjORYHIRq/J66JYL@JVbEsoYR5iKRdulloirYlYBjASxXFmIXwtXF1SYYswqtNQStka2RS5Lr94VYhTFFYCf@qTHKGmMfuoQxtVl/yZ8nuOoa4Ap0LCPonrS0yDDRAmOf4o7kLRYHxHR32NC0bLOhFaEnA@kYRNU0tYoTBzFc1y3XgcTeBeC3marjQRqfsNlMT4X7me4x1k@tC1To2PXJwe3adv9wO1g4tb2DQ6MnoGKL1bgYu4jH4lfwJ8Tu0w4ije8gYrHIHiI@OP5z8fuxeDyOo9BAqLcxEhJs5yIYlKrgV4ISeoWLhEYz@fapaV2UshIfVgAZdXUVW1eoaoIdGZ@80oArYrYTeIAphMM30Fvl8zjCG1NejbzPtVL2yf6B/dDdMxjfoFHKtcR6jGVUCTc8VCu@b15srZ2qwBRZMXuajrH7MVqkLZZLmqhxj2qMnUpxtcI3dYyOyi@LL0svnzw/eH6wJ8RO1i7XHBzMZ@FCs7f2V78GEePZXJyxk1psWstV/WVm9bqkbmp4UFORVUDe99SClLmsc76uU0BBg5B3v/CD3HSzBO9aRoV3TcuntHpd3dBYMjZ69@Xv4ZkbF7ufbj9mcU@fsb/94x9pxb/9439NS7fiV1WPRp6LMYiJTrVQjF1cjC4uruDiYflYM8aRyhWT4OZTFGqsrqha1rbtKqsour5RTOW0@3ZV8eOqRTUZ86SYP9lSzMe8Sz9Iy5QgKJgNIS@xgFUS2z0085p6fxO5RQ33m7Hwb9PwyjEhVnry6pIxeOnUu/2@qZFLUVjlrcQ230qb7C1OQLyV1tirWh0nsFUIDIfnN3A3Dk5SxespZSPOwPxh9cZVtZliNMIPduJLw9iwT67x@skaK5eveW3Y8GdsePSHiQIPD16DN2PjC09MbCQVpdv1z3PaNFi@DqywoQBmJ8l3v/Drmlb42z/@lcvWZeszDazDcrmgarGfqT/7GUS45aSEwLSjiQw80gAdoUnIVnxOXu6IQmxiow7M4wcGIpqEqEGYfRusenwTzlDroVpq8cO6ugmKtoEbqdOkQ9PhOMmqIIS6JunIbr@TJhhsA7/2Ac1WuBC@gkHQtbIaiFThK3NQ4DGEztTptDxr4o5oX0SC0qnNNLsHSSCHr@A5aGu0AdyXyxKIMmXjZlKOskdUIw2JDQ3Pw1PVoEsRvgJJ/JMZ8SPmOp5VgDFNGzoCGaMQnhTQbUDeTcjb4gla5Jug0vMIacax44ls0KOFr4BqQFQwQWNg5iZEqILM@QoQAMqQ8AGbTbbJskl2YaZS1fmRbVe4JBxPvNODfdICJkNoXdyXHySuYjzwAv0dvwWGfOHXMChrEc8ACIfBp5VrYAFgcnpDFYwOMnhvUACLDg1KUNHYvXtzrGo1s5tkVCKEf2qOcOyK6sFejisAC6ynj7oVMc3wMLxq4BuyHVA8RegC10n8FLxqJCkT8fVKEOD/vZkWOfJaVVFAFQvg1xdvFR0gGSRGsvM67LDNGlO1YpKFyHcA9w4hRQewhSbhyfQjWfssCLwCDH8WC07aB0F0HB0P9Pn2@kZ5Bj3iBI85x@OSuDDwN7jzA5FQoO2Pg9RhKiiKaVHsnumCuULz3cFZbImsmsRk87PrCA9a6K3lcIm0lk/ig1JhbAZPHc8U8/NZo7NQOg5UqDdybDqEjA5JwbXswBEgo/zzmzjaE/scP4vh1w0ljmLk0dlNyPmIMR2qRt8TpbQ44dx2waYNaJNmRl9mnWGXaWWWIEajc6bsEFySEhHCbdB9kcZtyxgCSkeGQRuVvIqi9EFzmrTpsK0nJvDVYM@EXsX2FP/Trcq5eWoqx3ist@T0cD8TP7oghsoWNj8@t@0fbGU5zimzzFODD/MmFg5@8Bho/6DApoGy8x8QtoKLJrRsmmUgOM1jwa8IjyJ3ltKRtGuJWfLmM6uuJVpYo5fUyZgufpb1TLcj9KXrUvANXm/mBUfH0AEo8C6HItfwD42oxXE7eHgaiuAfglOj81dknD4YJcD8DA6PQacwco0zhqargH0MCM1OcAwDtmIo7VeoA6C2By0Lz5QbuxU8PAQwcbuJDjQ9X8Db7COW1QSMyE/28U/hARhY9bVF6BAGSbEc3rgLFSPTmDnKFWidwy6E4bZ1n/0wfcDd6Kbz/ubszdZ8cNjpUF41xptF8JKPvGDrQH6moq9BYAEwXILJWkJMAdiUmBQ56DD99eSc2wWSJRV2E1KaIQSf1ACFVIXgu80s8v0KAQIe6B4/5Ng/ce78/FymYxAnrikbHn7TwcOPUSujvgnqsqOMjeHI/3qeiV9N9eHOXRL/lAt@onxrSh8HL9@b8acg9Lyav/QkEe95cewcz/CTBf0hHZmEZxV5xFB7Jn3upJPwV8Jw/tOa6YuA/yrIf1IpfoVAGEMw0/Qs3UkDsHS7c5runXerfsAZNUgADrVoBJ54OKkbvAy9wGWOemEMZ4xyNAxqW6c0FQqQRD5AO8@alzCIOQte/feROYVEtnHOtl1XnyUoPImxkYETM1J72Ay6fQoBJ3Qz7IKflGlOG7PmQvJpmBw6tcAaYi6ehyRc3A6UH5uK4VMePoXwKQ@fzjMNsm1Mm1wlQ68rLA5yPR6jF8REMLMgzhU/YnQeQpBBx2YqB4ExZwt@V/Dr1Ch1QG/@BvVYCxgDeGIEBDcSSuPlSeOkaXvG@UYzpfSB2UUiBNQ4gG40iabn3dCN1LfOrJHjLXjZeHoi9Eo@3ujVGfjcwHkFyxhWEDEGp5eJB971h/4SAq4Q@AUGCKiHQSCqBtvjhJmshsf0UiAwTkOc05gj1vCRaZL25Qf5fqAucdJzwkYBNSOA0D8sEqAJISxoOfwLPoF0eOE6ECeIK9FHR4Z48FK8GQdKXmsqXNZUqZIiWElSgCaQHdXV2vWiBOFQFY1rQZFiXvn1H0V/7YPR70G7WI49MSzvMKpCtKngOjtQIfzmQlRl9VqkXgEDZUO3DBd6rl2un/q9NWSzoQRmBs8Hi@Cd42eJE5HK7yR5/dBePtEWKyErzGo1KOKsxpslbxcBSTnBw2Sen2wWMIKfngsQgJFZmszwk02jyaa1GhccbLoi2XkEySkhOeVJeOzpCiSbfjKwnsLv2WP1NEE7xYWAIsBTeTcKatBIZPhtYpzR/gIPhQOrKshzLnOIC3weQhUb@azTXJp7I4J0RGhdA4CMeANAl38MsCJcF3iqFL6FMoqTMpBR/M1nAy4rgMFIBFf5wamJkMnIBgaFX0xRPwBtV0w1BFGlUV78y/CfmA48g5960zOzGFNd9Mykr/39o3g2kbKRBhrRPtRMDgUyWjLPbf/EwajOEcPv5g4c0Ora5w5LLFG2wV@Z@EmVtuW0laGOK1PwE2H@Z7NHs2RgP@AMCbs/csb62MnlKtxoMontluXPbQazbzv4ZYHI4cmg63Udw7PjY6jUjtO3Tc9IMzzX7tTwzQ7DP2peiOrJvtPxBMEfnuRmLILmfIWqbquFHy1ttRK49C5ZCRcE00o8ZM94XED7F1yR9CCefKAHo4TT/sLojJN3w8STwP1kx2bnNHEw8gNxKHWbgQzrgP4PoQPQYJjnzC1HOmUYVen2OEHH6w@codMHrW/iyQKmvgZ@fw4bEdJHI8IlzXQ0aSuR8@CplSQ6aT3pJ/3kg5OyT7SEngzTa4sAFoiRZu51GiNl3SXZtVZmx5MF@R19OL5HUXyPbseXrPDrOHPTvMYDPyzrbGIOASLO0cjejQYWHeRW9wY6C6iE3qhX8QTvjWKXVn51EdNtiLrtR5d7wB/p8M2DtxDxT1fR//YKDJLvvm/16fgl56MZyJshLkhM0MdgvGCqMwHR95NJIbYku5C1H75nXhAXv8O1hyoEqLEkuGw8IBUa5gjMbi885D8AfAfP42KrG3xPK7BqPHAJTu5Zmp1qq6voYatrWPrM6Cb8mOkI3KDEh2Cwkbx6v4KjoCOh53BbLwF9VzIMhW4cic4jVVawjJ4@SyZXsxWPYobcQyPlhOH@avph@A3RjEN8NT5aDXZAPB7D4dgzE4c/R7PRjJ/BbfFPgvhylPc/vCbxwIK7CQJ04L2nmp5nm7xNfB4mwiK9R48QxpUXi4xH5AYQ8Tiem3X4YSS6u6RQuZFEtaCWhcWvTyyvcfO2Go9wRcCTfArp/VjyLqZ7b56LsBoHNhdhOx/WhdyAjKszOp1EFCL3ubXGHPuGTEA/GqezV/QqrSUCNUxJkm5skrlN@kVSQMt4H5444PQpPBFg3xi3OEMFZcMxLf/jWoxChvooorX4PqCkA5QIFTnJfTQisYTADdEvrsI8Oyvz7NzIs7OQZ9gCFrOMRBI6C1n6tYDVc1sVWEZvvEI6YxDazvC4TWzDZTu6i6MVF3EzXjHTLH4Wr4BAjhvxym4ChHK8G688JIcXrxyR4zRe@QQc87YVv4xXgmaBEVx4Jcd99PdFOL534pWdRPJKGOunhhfkK8crYZ1CnC3@ShQBUmC5QWvEKTbb8Ys5dg3o2EipTDPkGC@N5hONw6Tpl4F//j0Z@tIEBuIY5wZFZimmLnQakR6D5wPdRnCS@ZKWXPF7892DPVrdFEbBbFJg40XTEHhQw2PxRWHEEcNQmtGAJyCIcrOyHCMW6cneEx0/d@BQquTF/Il6MukD3QSFNyByc54JfUTITx/U1yIIXoHvhycmXoXnDXSC7AgjnJNNLkELifoqfkuhsK4XcfFrP1pDNNa9GAk/hR5E4bVEYCMyHXQ4mpzDzEbOaJFJKBTXz5vRNDQoxxslcu@1ZCQV/Ja5Ipi8/ZKhYIg2/uRtxYmkQ9QWRBAGNjJN3srCfoFkMQbNZV1EU@WND1CIyBxo4UbnlD7Q9NB3UjwubtLUV6zqhoK0PEuSXItiEhLLeALURB/z3EPjdRfPhfow8zVIOcWxlgQCiKQMc@Hy1fkA/d3h@nugUAdEuJbBMsV6eVd6U72@tZe9hrk1z/ZmBWJgmj1MLlWOwhzmJAfrIKKZ38ZrN1R8XPLBlXyeaQj9mrYfkC20Ce6g23XbgsNCLcE9W/Q81cDzVFtNqJsaiXUmB0qLjDn5cHjBQ0znRbsdV17wZVWMITS@rVsfXMHuYgVHKw/hUQHcayTnrdyd2LTKZd62QWxzHxSpaoVxQU7TpWE1zz1B3NPUbThtCx4HrcOHB08ffx063WKxmPT76NkcP2y1ONYa9uMcMi2VDvuDJWaLlsavqOBkNw7HewPHHa@d2OINWcKFNSgDOuQSsJ/fxpO@LIvI82ttF9LxuBGK@rBO581AX5BKqOro2GWbPl3HQBBjnNjQfSCBegv0TpO1lqTvhbRa@Kn5Vou6r1YLFy@1Wn4vhlUTzIgnfxZbUyaeSx/n5B@7ORcEOuqAPTxgLx5tH7PjR7ts7/nOJ@zrB8/Zi@2nx7jL/dnzB4/3dxj8dp8e7TJhYQklfhgMDUqg60OjY@DXHpmWyeQYQd5xRjMudxI7Se5/pA/ZI6dj4DTVpqcP7w/4i2wb4zpPtQvm6AzHME36ENzQHON6C/pyGZixqNx0ac8fruxnELcNNu0Qbd6h0zV7JsQV0PYdmYYXbBNjlgk1CPI22ACc5koSfqSMlg7RxwdxBdY5JNchPs7dABidr79CEmMM/lWzrsx8woXXB1PwePfwyRHDAxN2Dp4@3D/eP3h6xPYODuH12df3n34M9Nw/Oj7cf/Acgyjik4OH@3v7O9vkwRHIyAxPMvhi4o1vRUHG6ESVzinOfMsjqP7wbXHUGzV4dq7T7kePxSc2Sh9Tt8w3/09xT7vVxo7kb/opRJuEbmh/kUAIxiQGTOJZAhk@kpsDxGnstul7je3rNmAncM/s/tgX2P2/j7CvMu8wv/YpZutDUqvbhpDJnDM5J7i7JZVKpVJJKlWVguZ8ybqKcPmCHpd0VCCcucrBmw8w54vgdzzhVEfBZH9gH0d0cd5cQaxTbTBYNmC8lSwVmtDJFl06j7gcC7w7IyhRhAOHnj2hgJMRTzMMhL2FNiqo@@ZACDSWFWioaBZgIyhlsFIWdOfN/Ly3TiA3oLZGp4cxK7k2NiKUL1j0tTI1KVlEMWkrg0DRe6HWRX1QsaQ/AN/DhyVZ7XDAGcQz/YEziOf8AZeiNbQdEcsyx9Vw/wrFs1jhD79e9nfoWFi80B82fdrFrkqcuN@oS32h7wzDsBAdutmItTx0@6IfNcKQikSUH2/96XR4YAR83xzIRD5KJNs2yGmDsGnhUYM0e@NrXDEVuAHthPzWMBJO2c2JIzQOCroh3ynV7vhdNoGKTXeI98QqRuApb8jlg76LifxB@j1iQLwHLomHLrctV4XBY8tByc2JGn1pI0n3ISoTtO8hsDmBwD8CBgAl7tfwGzRTkUMqgum1JCs7UQ84EvW2f5j5gZ2bV40gUUBabTm/hl@/upLIXmKfpOwUCTvooq/BAJaVdJTZ6g1gjJNYpdtrUAo2Lnr9Ych96CRbQCdONM1BbpzYoLYviriyNqRDusZur2tUeg5cfE@t58CUj6mVOJ7PzrX4iq81Bc6HSZjt7hAd/7x3HRhnZx4eIt0EqH6BhTCdlaPyczwkTHj9acWy4w@BtyGulje2N0@zf3zx8EpEFgt8I6kyOsT/wJhYFwwPOucjg8UBrrvkSFNXWUVX51ha2uBJaYmjXAGDfeBFCPu61/WSTmNz48nv6DGT/k4fb2/LXCqLkkleYxtdOLF088SJqtKjMmdCmoAYshOQBVnvqC8ewdTy@jV6yWAvlIAiXZQjuG9PXRQlRYhq3flVCySLvK9TdreG74oNsqiILztG7xezP/Kfnc3y4oabjw1KhEFOR4loT0Euuq5hlkLz1QS47YfBgfx@PLjVB7Hj6eGHoG0/CO2HcMsu3g@LpyUD1uPB/vEAWJ7c/iGw0HbvfsA8SU5C05yumdOby2hr2odr/DLRdzT2AAzOvahB0UCN2q66dEStQkQ7XMA1wcQLosOj7erBgbB5fwJlQe7hlqEpxSDCnhXvY2vbsEvCLqcXTWZcZ148qS8Jizb176HBPJV494gKuQbxJD20sIiv9W6FI5Z6cmahJQRZ35NAVJRLYvdNyaDoRAK@gz0gIBt3mtFAa2ozMzz5hJFpBC7p5vHa2LThJwtrnrvxFszB2ARk2gT5bfQsmd5/H3l9vKbq4QUWRvXBBjdhJQ3zDewTDqHiPmTM5ZI9@EC3qC5FI3teYGcU7dDwq5BcYf88QxEj8SKc18KGWJeLY4kar4/n1DKHDBJxGvDR0lMmskUzJCgRT1/WzQ5140nPSU5BsMjEexFfm1wBxc/u5BRG1NDzZFkvyM2xNkfYnCgsz1A7K2GX7s/0BG2hV9LiIV0VSNsHq8r@c6riWSJRk6L51MaoRIC8srz87Huw061QxbM/C5vnkLT8HF72YX8fg4zGEan3gXNre55KjxngAdKxab0aMKmCsNSZMqck2k6TkYkf4MJ6IUAGA6bjVZPpWl0xSuE2HTrPSCZ0yjLRBmMI64byqJmg/t3D1aFA/m59sz9eHw82zISmg3dolf@uN4iC2CvPiNRifELX1uS3YDDoUjb2Z7pEKA65MT3obEfedmzwyq3CRDpvM1vSkt5JbHbrKV0DVULqxRzeLovavVJavZctlsym7tR2q2KBAim2ErpIe2C7huyZDbsPIUAymPQSOH2QD9@TaA3@Aw6eAglkIm8@h2jjfhc3ogismk/owhxpFiplazHd@62o4XcxwIdnP4mE7T2FgqSFre7vuNM064VSojwgF/W7DpTy7GzOpqLwDRW6CCkJgnsTvxsTFnpqKEtJdK9p99A@Cg@2ghFrz8hy0s8XVwsrLy1qXdcbepcnL8@8hUbZFjD5@t3L6Gpw0/yt3bu4bomO6P96PmqMv/4uxPJz8QzqWnrK0WyLK@U8BRB9AX9XxcsCca5E8BVF5j21hcjxPYRCzIt4H16aFXwVB22a19BDIsWlYuFScSG62A3LlycrZ@VuuVC6POmeldDJb7hYHi4WFx388BRmUZAxfDJ/MjzDOdXUugbda4HX09I1gtI1RJBrCHx55w/C3m5l701CG4cLAFSBSVtvUqjzzbIzaM2Gvie5bnDjSDWZJ5BjLVwgWTPkFVREv3fSJ6M6phkCZtArHqxmoxH9HbvWTCF31R/2KEXFG0TWErfhrTWj3JgKpFGALCehikqI/gUAJ87j4MEQfx2zFXW2yMu1IvpOugaIEyxJ4tA@tW30KUREpS/XyZkV5QK/cYFI4FXKt1RMrK/TxcrAalGOtHhoyuEPyGGicIaPeAACP306bcAqaOUekduHBc3H9yI@8BfSUQ3JT4YM5C1aKWIKmn@Lb@TfROXXgQBM@Blec@WkilOuvGAhyb6DpFzAqGXJjT8eM6BbJXfKDDYWYXN95Rg4WYoTjbBaSSb4PnOD5GRawT/ZgmyR3iaaofO7nJ1IQufU8i1CWlKXUtIG/nTiYo5RLKuKqcwGKWa@Sw3UdMH26F0Aw2ostoJOB5BmWszE5MBH8u@V9S/q@qMTrPNMI8/p2Yn0bCI9x@mMVJwrBxN8nGnNzGRnvsX57oQdZ/Mm6ioLWrzkoKcbOViSxHlLD@WNcsNePYwzb@iuZK7UCeuJhKyR8nlK73PKbKKMZnCdfsLpkr@XZM9rLBN5Xyfrx19LdlBAxrPS1iTFpblu2HllyVt4ZQqymQ3UFIKL06V9Qg2qsvTBlOIEVnCo56dhu1GOoSwWlcShMWNvrL@2c3KR8cpJo8FejBMDa8oYMahEdS4S4UbksAj1UPKsAYJgIqMJNXI3VOGxLDw2wGKuWVUte0FODHBoWnqIl9Ev8hb/qMGeRE7ly0xPnGHMR9x49m5OEoiE7qw9nUxJaYLuIvxRNuqBWSSue5yGOF1I7BlaYF1nwD7YLVSDz2o5YQoKJSkm6K5TJKXjDEXFvvd1ISbeWX/PL1hvfFhj9zvBSFRwm@GTF5aVcHAfBtEwwkhPFK8muur3O3jqSAu@G3KhljFDlpbxuCWGaMzsOauGlj2c38Mn6ZAOhXJiHyHfoIFInBBdtdvoTIYesL0bFK2ocQmHOavSHbNCA8bMsyV2Mw/EVcSnprDbb5tIcM/x6EFKR32/EeQsWKNFsPqxuKmtUF52Sfp09BvBWGIwpa1Z1p@vwsZvW2/wPPdFsfCsaJDsWh4HF3LPnscOVkAklbCEcQCXi88tyzgbbvDZcBYBemIXJ/oPwJvBddDtBlYFZgzKGMGiNQoG10EzZ1kHgT4ERrjIyngyiX7YvatBg5U7sOjygRnRSzjy@DgMOAx/cX7m4@IGnZV5Fh5axafN0NXXYRMJqDxOWj08HaYDCwwTwPTAQpfBEIiy4IokSnT2LHGhtcslKqKAGhjnxDib0GTo9oZhA3qGNFlWB0DxMUhcWbeZwgTqa3R8dA7OTUMA3WNiCigE1FHSQzhY8tD8h3AQsmHqjN1XPZMH6dejsQLDPRiEIH1jAlOvUDEDd@jgo7e1Q3G4v3P0sXJQFfD8/mD/Q227ui02P9EZNx6UU0hd8XZ/F6SLPk3nU/N9@GBXDqGkTQlWZe@TqP7y/qB6eCj2D0Tt3fvdGkAD8AeVvaNa9dATtb2t3eNtOn0HCGJv/0js1t7VjiDb0b5HtapiVlxO7O@Id9WDrbfwWtms7daOPlGNO7WjPawMT/Ur4n3l4Ki2dbxbORDvjw/e7x9WBTbM2q4dbu1Wau@q2zmoH@oU1Q/VvSNx@Layu5tq6P7HveqBICMBo5WbVcCysglbWKyJ2rldO6huHWGD4qctIB4guOuJw/fVrRo@VH@pQnMqB588CfSw@udjyASJYrvyrvIGGmc536EK9MvW8UEVQyEhJQ6PNw@PakfHR1XxZn9/m2h9WD34UNuqHpaEtbt/SAQ7Pqx6Au/zo6oBBlAL0uF58/iwRnSr7R3BnHH8Hu0dXOjkj0AYwLICRbeJwGgGga0FIu0ffEKoSAfqAE98fFuF7wdIU6JWBamAFhVbR2Y2qBCIeGQ2U@xV3@zW3lT3tqqYvI9gPtYOqy50WO0QM9TQIOMTsA5Uekytxn4CvPgRmNVSnOtRd4rajqhsf6gh5jI3cMBhTXILkW3rraR5DkPtGkqUsIc6A//SVKy0Jj9dBxhqclIjM11HoyMmbe1vV2FGlnGr7DjhGGad1VQoJTMNZhqdCK@JkDXN4PyqXQ@7rR76mOpirPi4jNoeXl3j4r0fp9YDNzdJ/QoVyGTq9Q@VOmx0D@t113tMyQQa3ysh1eAP5XJlG/G6Adx5o@JnbY3pvp4g1MZTedBJhnp4AIE5mfpP2fTNvwxckc83A1kMnfcRsFIdRXxscoFHKSAaydkRLyyJqyTNBL2Hkh2ooKPA5xp11JOiZSRl6kXwp3sbv/DkYHwA6czqrnweN7GERvg1UNVwJRQSgf7IiARhi6rMRUHwW9spmNXhnj/X7vWajuuqMpR3CPvAtuN@p/h50E4Vz6bLE7J07CxD@Edq301LGH3@LEkmZL/kBtQyB//Uh/TjKmw45gNqTakqUlZLpaXzlIujRZInZGgLdK@gTsY137vKL7WPuJsrLD0vpb6/1d95bKG9IIakhQnvhMqd0c/bM84AA4xicQBJQhkhI583yih7E535BjJeYKabsImWPzBXXwQ0rwNJYCF75XfMOnE2HoQjE3uQw28OKu82j3d2QHQits9Xl1@slCwddusXj38/YT0UN5aijvVhHod1GiUZo2QLFj40Uox43TH7EwPn85gRQ7GrTqOPGOdB220kLZlQkGFzI7y9p4smenaAdLAFBeCYtRS/Th2ZkgGcRFNdbM2lP6Ilvg9rJeIBaczSGVOvjfAPwtbDXw1x3SDJQJLFKJIucC7sLkju2TvKVJQ2NxS4B7PkbMXHHMZN04BUXWQ/i9619CZ52@jFiE0ZcbxSt1NJQGI2jYVQdhVdHtnvKc6IVABT9DD48ovkN3j8JAPcUbg7PxpWhodAxh1dEvXUsTJaNvpEQj7De3gwqJqqaV2glt@VSNHYk@pkHRjEGA2ECl5/gja@ScAlHUckXSVZwL6ed8U35lQM3oFwSpJj5Ttw7rTmSCglFT9EvquoFIJh6SAnTLUbXYelsnzScSwUORNk@il6EPx/IU2mwF@HHSdAj6llBAF8FCUJKtMKtq9ElPBGHTQYpxsxNc1Pn2Iwd2bHXOiGydObEfvXAAlk74zVh08U9rDlTCEAMjkqNszxq03SLnzYOr22XVkcz0m6jcu@I@RcoaaKCbjZlTOPll2eOlvBF1e4rGsyKtyFouI1b9zOadTDlim1lRdPIpvBuSr@R36BFCB6wBOXXrDVapqzCnKUKTkgQy0ZE05TR0yCZendvad2C8IIkZmQ/fLkSxEKQG8gPpPtpDtCeoLNc5MRF2kmFkcUBQ@jg@M2GScfGbLunAwxOwHCedIkZQheIzK8wQmiw9ApVF8MTThPyFAEK4mtDuM4gyhu3RyQlqbVG409aSaRQzX2x10OSx@wVkvlyHGAD4mh6S6fE@/8MaDceVyzmcXyC4c9D20XsTJWS8jyeGVKo9cbwNLRx3YDjl44dnPio1Q6BN3oaiDjF8J8Fg6kRkIt@qEaXDbx7p2mGY4IT6hF4RC9FZo54g9q0mWAFqIcnmSUXREOMK/i0Q2ldAxHi0XhrMcp60ATCktKRFwXK@L2lnMxQWXI0IAoGEZ6c0E2m1QPnjvo4XfTG/yGcz8ugbrNoKkjkxogSRfInVTrUozHxpCb3u9FpNGArkANiKZEkRVp2lAV5ugXkp2kXZMdR8fE2KXUkh@vRzOpspaCimLGlbUD861koTORSksyNKgOFlpcWiZUpm247u7djFG00OSxtbBPu1qkrPEiovxELR3xieWmfvqET1LJX34S4eiBL3jGLZegiDCuWfFcdVLOEX5oU/AxDAZNUycKK5mm30f1G219el3iRaU6lGH/Gv4wCsawA2jkw1GeYNSdP/UuuvWtXsdvh73Qh30aBnUfscTDxzE9Yoe1B72biG4DooSmkak5jp85vgyHYcN3fS5ZMkJzRcOg75hmCsPBuHLBYSJIc45GgPGVmsTf/XSMNF3m@XJcyEr6n5I9XtEt3Vv2WXFaYT7RRwBSwG2kLCjYh3RIjkmG82lpIsP5QxkMHM9FVvjuPRZ7CYxfAonoGCaBsUJmwizBbATuzO7F@KQ58poUg3CAgZaC7QAvtokc@uz5eEsxSJFXaCmwJoqrBaMon6KMMA4hPozvJ/fSi38x9oDAT6BffDaNW6YxAom4loq2FPF@RUYZBVzIPDAkGU2SGKRY2A67hvshXSkxSkNNJo/vowZZ/sCiSIbZm@BKHJEObHzw0jqnDiKnPnZxUpkX8y7F7cAlSGXoFO5n2OB79rM0@PEQlzVnKJi2JGTHQPo@UjWASngPbMq81kSZYyp/f8QsLT2211IELE8zOTPuI3ZstXIhD5SQ51c81uoNQBjbKepJU4/5aNjrzz@SevfKjqmR2abRuuG63zUEZmYrw2S50CTSlsf4OC5ZaXxSTJOkGFmaAQ/h9pWeNZuniTgq13G8levj79DhPprFdlN6UtH93eSxj5PiNVr0qolGDynCHYOUlvT3kzo0vH6/BJEweXtVJ4lRR5FRH/OjASpFJk2lx1OIuE/inqJHEyiH9TaBdmb/3EvUtJGcCnmqkhJBLpGeGLgdnTZBLvVbaHyBYeJ4hauFlF5wjrwxHeUVs@cYZBgTGCCuioNsrIdiDW7cWSk@otsBWk4drYWKKIngacO0cNBB/zXBKCq/VO5Ii4f6OFs8KzGkkYYEuwrK9RAk5W8Oryf1EUGZIAUM8Smk0C2akE0Xj2/Vz7YF8gEELk3J0tK34GFjXLEI2MAfM6k@wjVwXJUsmRhRyYFQJ9EAYwF2Ke1OwNtVXP2FA@Z4tG6Qwwg2EPzZwZ9FWQLDea8UNLWxyKg5xiyuJDePNldkN7hIzFD8juSXQ5GXurRxBQABYwzly0WAgGFNCXs8FKDQOybnJRCVfQQFy0UclvCRoqLGdp5T0pGoMsPzZSNHYVqOlyaM7FQgsLCYnidGBNYs07PEUGCim4qLkePF9PbEOWBBrHifKQ5dIXslSUPdc0xAuk654MYS5aQovILkYEp8vuwmEjV/U@rLgpFaSKcCfTSGJ9liOnW1kEhNVLu0lCyaKAn0cM1aE4lACtdEWEuFn/tHrilmyHNtE2psMhKrDGmfjdddwy4T9m25XyOxTk7Zao2h4Jme4Wr7VecrVhJB2R8OwC7m6cgAY7f/dGuVZarCRN4VQHHplLOLwxtCWrHaONVjs3CnqyLt6QAFak/ba4kPRzs7ibCv52NlaHQZDJYLhQIy8bkZ/F7ZVqMqKezlk7nzratOJ9@/@dPgw3meZH8Q0JUAa2oHHUCXwKCIcr1Bm2@GQBwgK@bOSkdW3OtftVrmFQx4QomdB93GOWU0BEETUKiNXj4ckQKIQMoJ9gs2ENv3RejRd@PzQlNCUcdQUBpNgq9tdXoG5MEPLbTP1idVBAwFs7JmgnnLLW98wxkEbzahzqLwxe632DzZfht0Oj1PfMT7hDFSwMxdusDOjlmgwFnwhJG8e68iikfrieA67Bh@xZjF5HUEpyYmdc@EiguPsfEPgnZ11Hfsk882TCvQ5EVs5iLGp/aE3bZdGSz@EWCZDwHtR@W@9PtOg@iUzgxTvRzB8RNg9KzoTd37JLK4pBOTNPt@biTqdHRzFKwBmu7SWkDFsqfupZbck10T1z4dFVtIwwLDkDhhzJXHlUBXs3@dWLwetlqPk4p0DQB37A9JRL4J5ecEIp0B0AiUww/oiVG0/y0Lw3onFVCEFzh4Wcek3MECdSxgWU8a5d9vnEqlIub6i4uiUtmEh2xWVDYrYhs/bG6KbXjfxPen5aXl5RLL3G33G3zcVB/vxCbAIA3nYuNisA2vkFZGvzG01sYunsuX57zSXL28vlGK8ieVTXTrh6e//ft//u0//itfkS//gy@b9HLyWWfK5XL5uca3uad3JXw/2T6bnzs/meufzbdLyGV/p6jhvdow68fmo7nBuZXhWcD4Snakap9N0WdkUaEu/Lv0B7@BdFkTmUaUz8ivEd8cRTI20wiM7wH6UZ7DFl5dOpDeygMSGQA6RnU89E4jQAM8mG@AkoAL2oFyeT5bUYp7DAejM@hTlYyMxENr1usAfVriSAroiwszVjbsRkEXNeDXtObl5lmWD7/hsC75N//5XdTe7I3EwqkjFgpiwRMLtk0/xZWX8NWdy4foncvZYDtg2x6kxEcLaGYoopAWerR/oLt2UuS2rDm6sgchqTAVlJm94Dy9@yNnGb5wLWpbM3ixpmAVCR0yYZHMt7nuHXTLN8hxZydcbWihUJe7GKrMOFHR/YtLID9iQ4C45ksmyFoPqsSTPvJIxqe8@iL72qLbhAgwkvXgzQ6Ne/wAc9FcV9o8J/ZSeM0Rmc/zV5wbS@wMTWhjCtcfI0AHKrydLJAn4Xxm3mIrb6OV1Ez2wjbbJ5mPbR3GwVDZpnOhP4TBBGzNbRJuriv9WqQhNx@vCDvUxytGVXba9ltYRpHLq84w7Et3BaodB9Q3XdsdjyTsUQLEcDhm/9rkCCNFgYoUleoWvixrLJo9bDqPhK50TYcOdnN8cmQQIf/ZgbF9mxrbbp68RBQ7MA8QUtqUr@WHnUhGXRkQsdv@4BxvB/RbdKHakM/NSJ@HV6mmMO61NNI5gkwm5/F4hqZk@gO/fel7IrPXOxr44xpMW7DyGTZyLrQQQzAhEjj4ZNXTmqcQ5hbJLiGK6KaQ5RBeXtAZy@vRuG9t7XOCXaqGggy7goMgwU5EyeA20VcpOsZc/QOdYKI8Ibz1aaQUsSR50dJIQrJNtxkaZhNDx1I1mGNHDxzbYlT1yFS8IAtd4UR7SQe/IMk7GCNA1m1LL0DpirDyEuvH2akddP3E5NTvWMrRP18SPC/ieKarKNkayVKXoBbjG@8QK1hHfk5GgeC5SYUzsmYcZ@Y0kte5Zcx5hIJ8a1v8vC9CfQEdXWBGniHiuBuysEzNUPEdGDlRI8t/gNDq@G3Ab3zjj5EVTzPOq9m8e/L5tHu24Jx2b0@/uoSJFMlqls2KjDzMVhJLjhWYGfNe4lVZpUUq1OBpN5nhtCvYh8UgASCSd04@589u84DQaQZvmD/NMEESXYaY5B@uL4/g8xNoZpJY5DPWjLvgqs53XhVdAXMr/WIf8geXfwELtakkNT3scwYtAEV@ur9fsctJlF9dKjxfKj6HnVA7GGUHwRXOt9no6jwYwVIiwu0sTD2nXxPckCDE3SjyS/BxBO3ka03Y9ySSTkpShMphTvVYmq2gTI55AvIDlSlcKrq4uDqPj4ePuOH3BLCcykuxoNh00OA@B@fPqHeJ9fgRyrW0dwhzJFoZsI0IqVCzCFldvnIfh7pquMyTn1NObGHsVgIC3ZvPGLNFt9fNysWam5sv4SIavWY6q4XVQnqMTgzRxAidk4up@VlR3Hj14q//vf97ZpjZWMp/HMDvMPN7ZmU1w4/wAG/P1Nt1ZiOzjtlW7jLjPOyB4fHFX/8Xym/8CeBgyngd/mwsK1gr48xGtkxFbjMbK/BQXFqCev/vL3@BNszxjg3vYp2re4IQKymKbPld4l1IFzVsJW9L52OxQo5ZCIMtDGFvDi9oGDVaWi2Qmi4jrSquAxn5StmjyCmeDLOGZCrEmgxlTwErIy5QxgqyDFKZULSEYbuhzDaQeWM0xZcnuZUIdgBfpDmHrlKbbjyJ0GRojrdF0IEO1wj7eX7YKLyytXnHmq1sSkpqCYlbOylrV5@V/h8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ngq5l)

Windows XP cmd supports all the fancy variable substitutions, including `%~z0` (file size), `%~$path:1` (find file),
`%tmp:a=b%` (sub), `%tmp:~2,3%` (slice), `!tmp!` (with `/v`).

Windows 10 64-bit cmd doesn't support 64-bit numbers in `set` command, `set /a x=2222222222` doesn't modify `x` because `2222222222`
doesn't fit in 32-bit signed integer. Windows XP cmd also doesn't support 64-bit numbers, but sets `x` to `-2072745074` in this case.

`set` command must be on a separate line, `@set x=aaa& echo.%x%` doesn't print `aaa`. It turned out easier to fit full OS/2 batch code
instead of `set` command on the second line:

```
... &:&echo 335&exit&rem ...
```

`&:` comments out the rest of the line in Windows batch, but not in OS/2.

Windows 10/XP batch code is on lines 3, 178-182:

```
... &goto e ...

:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
echo 336
exit
```

Space before `if` is for Oration.

Answer (score 2):

## 340. Perl -x, 15114 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a a    z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy4iiipsddpsdoh (22)S2&:&echo 335&/ \&exit&rem ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//n&goto e nthteo18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1t@.7.8.2<auaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__






















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hatax#8;>0::&&1Pr"9?3"sge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogr61k:4op>astd[]!!c;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1*\'\0R       
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSSbfUt6pULalu3b4UiwWSIIkrEmABoESWpIrunt1et@2Z9fS0He22x7fdM55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKq8iNiY2MhEcjnycyTJ0@ek8@27g5@9rMYPuyZPZz1h7bHPMP1WNcxzwxHZg9m7L5uunktKwgYatvpT0aG5bkVIcZUxoa61Z/ofYP1zKFnOGnmGgZrG0P7HPw1xjYn1sQ1unWwZRmzjHO2b3XMLkBgnn1qWOYbwwG/HGMPjeHl6NJjHXs00q2uy8aOaXnkm2fsmQ6W3qRzyvS26zl6xzNtC7wKjD23hvqo3dUZBR87Bo9UZACqc0pxFn1KjD2xHdeAFOyO4bo2OpbBUXdM@/H204@vhVcz7GMdMjUeGtNryasqe2EaTvd6DI19ery3d901yz6RbIvt3cySmmPbE8/e967Dz7PtvmHpTJPLsnbdswDI9IxhKVPKLHiB357pQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQwpnTUZtwwkCup7ueKbVZ@emN2DewHTDeBTaHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU2IZPd8KADa6rJTY3ZuO1C1PkzbGs4gotExeyZGCfIBAPFJeAODwxnpM6hMywMiYDpzIRtDI4CWFGIQ/qHRnvSZPfHGE49B3rqmq7eHALQ9Y12jp0@GXpq1wQ@QSe7nA8PyiRbAyQDi2Oa5@mJCWTPmtK13uywD9Ar5ODWYCVijbFVYNgvuzHYAaxAqyJEPjOiXl9GYQt1AlffsCstnMuC/G7pgbvWha/uZWcwaelrQJqnOEO4zx@47@giw0TUIp5/uP2Nux3bABj8My9vNbWA6usc2N1l89@nDOKuH1SI7bSGsohq7gCqIBZ7sTB9OgEKiNWFD/ThhbAGrLL4Wr7A4oEXLsFyO5aB5lpiWBySpmTIYoJ1rWRV@BaaVWE6FlpKPpzGdnqP3zaHBofQRShEJXMszDd6ZHMuqJR6ybw97PFiHEiuybIkViqyYZ0V4l1lZg9QQdI6p5Tz8CvADaGXIigq/bI4DmtM90CnS2g7r6SNzOPOhE/gOy6usCBAhvypA1koAAb7ZLP6y8KNsLT5R2N4AsD3QzwC8NDRPkesYIePBKlTgo2xsKMT5kLXy5N0BJg@oA6TlS6wIyRcAEznIAmBWK2m8EO7AGA79KAMXo1BOixn4Qa6LgIMSYD4DeMwgIovwAzvwNA2YlwacSgPmo6ngroE5i@AhXAH8ClCNBR9XA909hYR4OlqXEA9cG8CoiGlkVCoiCCBATbEs1FeB5YAIskgE@SyDvENeigUGvKqkslKOlYoMcFnOMKgXFfKFFKICj1QhPyoCg7pXofJVyJMKmFYBqJrNMyGCaDWL/hA3C3EBLWoO4uTADJWmFvAH8YAqVEhShTQ1rTwnQMiblofy5rNEmVoBarYIfoA3DfKqASlpkFutBP4YtwQ4LCHhFuNpjggd8QA1gqQONAjIyEN@CC6EBbNWzHL86cPxQG8bntnhMds9jFrAJlBANELUDBYPvjnEJmQlA2CwBUD2Naj9LLYU4UqARsu74ijLA87wAps7MjBk0sCgbGK/czpMWAGLSQJHXOSWwL6GQI/QRXR0ZGXYsA1iTAEc05MZJAL9pmGfYT9P3GUhGZc4UNvBbh26i67hOAzDgizgpolXuZO2a7yeYIc0z1cPmJ8BPLKnm8MwA9QgdY84KXzjLqQ3W8x2z7FH1GpHyIuGtj1ewfeB850joEf2uTHP@pwx6uPxELofcDd47weZOddJQCFpJpoqzxBEwnidgQkAKSlg26ZjdAj3ftEhdhYY/GIWK0yr38silAeRfinLxjbwbBfjWJPhsAIdhtFh2brSNc4UdOF912KfhXkIejPok3wQbR2EC8w55SKEdE@TqZ88DmrWtUeLReOMaj8s@sDEHmZ4rs@g9nrAo4ypPgIRiKGcYUGvOAKK4TWINQFCHhZrn3VtK@6FUM4dkAag0GFJSOJAnHjmyABx0YYoWOM5yjSyScpZewakTNjKySQf8pxcQ5QsXEcUd8hFHHhjgX6zO@kg1jBt0yIKgv7GRWHJMfQudxM8h52c6PBzoGMc@yKxjAYMeIRZi0hu0KsagH1fhOkQROzsDcsFOcyVmYkCK1B@3@4BsZ2bUHYQkSDqHHaHkIAoCJ2mckcWCOVIQKPTITNZZzxm4A6CB5DnXqYEfbn9hcnegOdwALJYZ@I4MzYdQ02YIwjldexeD6j3jTEeAAg26rLOrAPNEyoZqUfo2sSJOuPFYs5t6waEsVC623n2ddY3AO3Q8/dQnEeSnxdgPKYiECp0i0sFlg6YwiJ0xjNCC4AJY/RsW0b3rm24RCy2cxo2fUzMNfrUNKCd9ebMaIRSDlCpRdJZFziP37wQPiYoLC0MJuVTwceGBU2nA1QJjR6qD@t0m/VAK4nIAiiw6Z2OMfZ8OrGJnZlWRHA62EPBiVwlH5jsDoT1@2zzGtVA0JByIkIBCpKY9bEvz@nIa33VB8QEy5jL7pyzDGc3kocQZ9dSF19hmIUcvBJX5GFMTQKlSGISEw9ZCXJHszNAXughtyHBBVqbM7lZfHCLJu@MmNQL08bcqMB2BFkJnTAfq2FI8BveBCSPhwirvuCAQRcc7gCtu6MlkO0wk8Nu1FVWdBmY4l1AR7ZlL4EKyAzhYpBFH6oLIsYj5Br6MCRGai7uQh0hw55r49iRQR86HtsOtAzOdGakklGVRajL12QSYV@RBE1@sWuFLiOOHb6HvSBEGA9Bf6Mmhi0VRFQdOAUwMa5pAM@zeYqRDFOrJ1h@/s6J9XNigr7UsgyUcnVnxoFA8aB7hoRmzHQcYINn2EnwPijoTGSiU@gTQOdCzorooHZ/PXEZKXpn0jan19WZDjrKX7jCme6wHmoyDggd0IgS8Z4bT1bJnWJGvETFHnsKReVvEQJSIBmqPNED5Qg6iT1gNEczq5MQF5qYmGbixOuVxCQYMCKX0dhX9bF3PXdfgBsSzegU2jXZqqwP3bckwVtCN8oJeigyeugOyBnQCEFkL5e7bZ1dAvcAtXy6Q7FRuKSvKufCtAyrG6blIwLzEi2vzJNwnQ4ZpEivhiXA4FRy6iQWEPiemKCIIjgoit@3ogNJe9yP5BruOLFo4IIluCiSZBehkA8dQIIyY4LwYXZMr@WLK/fuBYLLWq0GxAbSFLDNbjKqHgQjPDJwaggskzTiJyJ79pGHbSORhPJi4CueGxCbgFJrdXbhDRxocWS/EiAQoFWwkJIDxPr1/NQ8nXSvV7SFjhhIxFYHQpPZ8cSqAJ0/bw2127AaX8AqqBBxxCoSL8Yn0DeIl1yxQkU/mGO4KP7W/KxEajiBOfBpdSmKeFTfbU7QO7PO0BcJuAkaO@dGbcj@qT8iEDKitC8TBI32RkvlQLA5cDjs2fbxo5rfFrmn0jatyoLD0O7oQ3Jex@BiEPfx/oPD7cOvt5bAGJrtynUHxcyVCtjVTqZS35ooOVmrrEdhzAE/bN0OGyMuhhEF35tJ9jQiKs060LlMA3QeHH5yHSUgCSE6KAUw4@@aSMPDgNAltHV3cK0TZv1UCpIMowRhmbTPApihAbOO/nqQn2eTN2@w8q5nauy7Y86GE50DCByVfSuIJ6PnNQEs8Gr3eI9IcUEKNS0cmZ2boiGD/HyMUvP1zJAoHSGZjw/2dg9rBNYfpJAoiOJ6IEvpTlcGmh9OuoawLAywPzB1WEqeZxzlacrrUgR3OgsIntctWwEfAKCuI9tMGo6CorkDyPvO9bKRq9QJKYDsBOG6XBmVhzofmtFIPrCL66DKu6wXJY95ZxU6Le2xQt/FbquTzxvFXDnabXXmaXajQGl0FfqBQG50wOvUldBFnkuRvljtZ//o8Y2MuyREgiogBTlzh0ymtNyhgNqLZLK4q@yAhmYPDfkFcTyRiUlFiQcDrHLHJeUzEn53anqJTJJ/1SSEhdS3t/e1h0Fgf@yPRjJIaUBdHHsmp4cTIh0XaMSyh3bfZhsQh0uHQYIgNq0s5nbftm7UkI6OWNQYzqkA/8WBG30MfY35hhRHihVVV/nsjG6558Cl1UIWkUQYIlAKhZe/0M90QNe83Ef7n@9CJ6LmM5nQnKEHUBCJQ@hCUyfiSg5MgoRkPz9LCxjOr9xo7YGHFJngwEL7jC6MuD33XupIHFNWloZfmqWv2jcw/oU9u0Za4MJJCwwRlO0/ffZ4/@nuk@3PTjwtn1@w5zLlAiAO0muDLCQPON6wtW7wponFQnAxaBsONi/gAhNQUIJh94nrAOOWMYjMM7CCavjMVOKr9sCKu8nrhTlHX@kLq8NJ6Ak2Ph7UjwiKdneIyojDp/ewP0f6GXje2K0oCrTywaQtg9KqfNGxh3pfoXjQMQyHioqqy/4Bjmu4y2JAZtyZwWPwwS0QHWY0gqgPRzYoLzRJiKyBJTh4GrUamv0B6MI4k2g4STmkYCqN0gUNAXRlJSwbMWCyAW79b1BPIiftr6haidO1mtFyihgEW2j@EHatZ4DqlIDeClCRvGZlJ/dO7rEZcGmEdB1IjMkbNMjhMuwLhgwESRo1RT0/QA5xCxwvRV5BOHo9wdFc4FJKPpMrqoW8AmoZqGkgs0o45iaNdK8zkDxbAniS3aNxgwgV9tyObvXkDd8QZBbkvo@gqNnGy5MTqwkC@sk9yhtO4DVmzYbaTFbZzSgbfvhkFah3oXhIu4ED0C4ZgTTpy1bws65@k511dWpdXaZ4o7Hf50hj9mQbBKk3NvDrrhFtexhBiXoqGwthFQz8VlkyIDTEqAK@EFMKNCjoaYH0FMyXBEIviodAOcC3IhHYfDSDl4NPiEf4CCrdSPemHXdpxB/lGhwtdceARBps7iCXdnF80IPeMaR85NJQucik2bkRx3F03eWjlRDJnywN4oOuFkKgUflwRNoKp4GBCCgWqefAOYCucNh0MB9lRKUfKA0SpDzh4ANIEBbNHvSBz0BkXpBtXhCeErksFunUss8thNY2WElqmx4f7LcnDk4amt1o2SB4VuNhABoVLsLXaXaxbXT4KCuPTKUAJVBnI2Nk41ACSFfECgwqgs5nJlEXdHHEGppVRsLpF4Avsfs7wMU6Bh8vkkaoRAFJ7bK45yjb0ueKLr0Bar5FtsLCb0en1qnSjwMELM4T0yiJPwJK0ok9okAvaLwFPR8E4q4wnnkDKDFQmKjX7LFhXdf5uEaYSFZpPjceB4ZvWomL@NraWrwSr8fTYNoC0yaattCUAtMWmSQyYTgZTRQjTSb0bVAMdGvGrxoB5GmyiTQwRcnhjTlO6I1KJdtM6w3V/2r4TUJVAOYhtIQfgBNP1mpoTCbF@jnO2YD8Hin7DtLOUccxxz4KvgoCAbf7OMgSEkC9R2neMaqom96OkVHNAaXRQBEz4cRPGpmT5snFSTd1chVPY@xkVa@BfgjMy0uM5L5jT8YguDVyFQl4W7KRrTSr7Vo8E99IJErSEBLSk8mPSsmUznGdiBtAU4mTkzig1MdOozNwCN40rSWTIaIgHz0TtIzhMBGXL0qQfjvZTKbiEDcZTwNbrsXjgJcOIsGlQuOIACeiPXMKqISGCV1cdE6BGCRNTmFz/dwYD2ZONEA46gZSNo6gzyf9cW0EcvEol3zD40cFugVNP5B7eTgQbnHwDuWl8Yxzd4Hn9ERZWLIS9LtnUm9ke7ryqQxKkxzpLuNrcUWSoCckHw6Jiv3EdLEJ65ZhT9zoSOPSAVBMHVyPBxNglsF6njRQlTkWjM7AZvH1@wCdhfM92JXg1JXEJ8ACAN2ODD9koiiV4GQJSBe0MsMEvkhrWmhURqVMcNYTjM3nC@PXcphaleKwDCZk9i3bMSRACcQQaBkKLWIS6sxfCbNPI1835iV8X@rSUPE2DeCIe0NbJ9xydh2ZDxqPIvFBP4coh0ZXGAL/6AF7lHldOEZX2RBoltZ2BtBDQGmQE2thbY18D8V2x13Zm0JUIYEdbtSTa3cgdJ6zrqZphU6@Vwn8kCoA2QOoJNRKLVBxAy9JBc@kX8m7fFgo0NGfHjzc5WMn1Nli94rjaK2R3Z2AXOnrTYeG1U@zXaAn07JHJqAhiP/mdHho2x7X8sGyamSGK83maDLUaczn@rDMrfE6dtse0lDQbVHn4SeOqw91PggV@G5/@gRk/efHRzW5Egmk6GejW9PGccjlyXJ87kfnHGm@NZgecjlhiut5EfutYJkcshnfo4AeE3@RHNRR4F5E96BJ4RyK715C9xEukANZ2R9FIGvo6AcsU0BcNIcrh3zHCzVzhe4rdbAwnErhuOA4z@2FqpH7mdfrLThnyflUQtY0nDvnyJkvnlvQEaNZyvNAuJJuIUwUUIHChAvqrofzmVe41mBgDIMZxEMQTHCWDPr2IYpPoJugJM7XvBkgSI9xMoQ4NE6xsQ7Imu6NYQtoU2OJhxZia9ROoA9TUHIR1hXmD3FXqaVYtj816XLuaYNqT6Mnm3U@mY2qk8O1NoUPvq@3AMRmvRosUFoVDFOKx8NgBJXyBjGomDR/f6Oo4WoMl8bUBYpSFVwFtIaplpFOpsXd5mVccQkNPSaenEw/ymifgfqBq8vW7yl9o4oJrsJXNfCJ@6Jqe8YkEOwwFB@f7gyAnbDUdBGVUD8Tq2cPuxKfDAO6YFyNwgry1yKEq978xY2G6QQL3mjFIY@KbDSyVu4G3GtVWr8ZILK6LgQEreSCXZ6mzy5ZA3q2M9kdD02vya5kz24NECXexLGur8Pjoqbj6DNX8Jey1Nj24cefNjJNDkEY6TjBVeK1OA2Wc4J8DPIQrq8FEy7I8UyPOnxacGBieVUZMjWluRDIPsDgCVRZmJBfIsz6pXE5L0vPAIU0YWDO3dkozYzkldwb6p5nWJzm@CzjanTz6SA/mRolv@XPLVRYhiZgQAA10Q@yWGVHxw93Dw9loFw3Ed/FiZoKNEe9MwA5ZFWhA0xGC19hH3Xj7COMk0TtXICmBkpGy48PRF0Fogc1A1JHFtE3nAQ4JnGOpQPONK1FEbkg5iMIl1V1PMJRCCxhJKFMBKyyNP/PLa5R@fmsAMWnCJOA7sS9CuDWTMoTy3wtu9CfkHgKQeJcJ4VuobaeIKa2riaJehxzhDPEoEiRbAglaDSY9AaYHgQWWbNZ5VP9EBb1LKeP2BVFqgpa9VtTg6qvgTNILgTBj157y142MlK5mVpfBorWkPkLdnn5I3ARwiJo11ia7HqC2vuNhszzwKf8OCN/TlrztVXpFbbODSIfWqbgwbooYjq0jGpxOdTiYitoZMhKaMQFCxKwhJi/nNqnWfInzg@qDUYjh0SSXYRI1xDl7PKScMjWNUY4BJPKeGVcBUomMKbHNpTmsb@UOioEUGv114tgmz0RxECbWpyQRR8uqStn14RQ6UyMxuNCoGmd2jStE5paGVnNo@AXxh6dDm/G7JnugF4LQcM88LDaqty5o3aPXksC0OyGP29ODjRu7ou8ICvqyiF9aAh9ScqLa0UWkm0bvYnVp0lGNDPp9R0hpXKJAvfabXNVUEACLv8KvkuCAZNCetbknKwGa7NxxAX6I2BcXEmZF/36MiO2gHfoHTyI5X//6ze6gP@btTOAjgIHGENDC7purCmpt7Ky/KhoodfyiuXj4JOhqRNiyHQXyI7uQJH0YWhYDprm2iUJuv8Rzhz4NQ60iS8QDm8hM55zPvEXfJcnsmzuzAKW2VkV9tqyK54UzfKA/tYlJHAhyDQoErEuXgnGlM@0RDRpZGN3ZypYG8WImHm9DybehL9BPr2zEs0x/m5rm37ITF5vqwZoiHrbNG6pckc/nXRtaXzaD@XUwpKw89LTVK8E4oA/69tC4/Li8wI6Zh/62eC7Kti8a1PO6XMXVbjWxB1LbVK2u9xGDWF0SwrOkL9XBTH9TU2hYTXWzCG93pMSfehAKP6iBwWXlEoRpJnX0DzU2zOUQQYfTmXhAgLgOLVOKpXJrphBHo9Xx0eFkeKXy8tjT@UOx8eyoQCFL1uV@GAZFdhfyHpHrUJ3ZY70oaR1I8aVzHzZ@oMbQcOpS4pjnOHEzdnSmptjHzukzmSoO3PTLSQ@z0cwW7Bq4NnvNp6ZHRvEgTFTi7KqBV1HpMMglhmsgJsnhKuG6RVZ5WAuQ2MX1ELsxKXQtJwF2B0PV4auoKn3YGh8RSaue40QiWyvwlTHPsffSvFhAKopfy/v0d4szdV7MCdp2Bnq0I@v7A4WxgBxjPEOQj03XYNeyxF7ujSjXme41H2xCQSje9HRurvI2jWHtsuO6H0bgvoOYIG/lxN0FJembkk05h0138KDgqUM8wrVh317WCj1FR1eK2t94vSQ7/vf9@VwIYdS1Ts4VCD@2Jbqf1fy9VPFOb2rgmiDl4PLWCPGW7rYZWzKn2JZXTpQDHB@bnnJ9jIliikrfERvRcI4s3Kuz4Lv36HrWIXaoOsYz0icBukOI5RLYPAcLmL/XVLL3Z5a9/2Y0g2wxbsKEanc06EBnRW9b1Qp0zLqB8ZQM5n3Z1G94cSYGEsVjYP2FwZuN75FyXj/TGX8Yqz7A/I4B4A7UMJQb3zN8L1yjf002m5lJvrQ7Bh3izKLTG0M0vcYVednYHiGhpsx@tZkvFCrC9qZdXg7ygbjoEnb3YXcoc@H8qHSHZLSgnzuGvS7VWPiGh6uA6vlMpmML8BEJlYWLLdpUtkw7hcmfy8kTC7zlOdhcTLNiRiXp0Foia40XMmCtFWKPQUulxXLtAxvhu/35KZt2x5@SE0BU@2aKIqBZEkram@rsRvijr9XhM2HLlwc8Gj3Vg1a8N7G1y0BP6g031bp0Zmf96pNCec2RzjvtGi9ffgmMo90Vyq4TxvHhPga2@FqWdIfDVHlkly8tdVxCdVuG0Odf6aF3G3wynL2VniLTMOfk8U5XD5zO59xj11jSuMZIMvsgpYyMEYGWW@R8vUuHingf1YGmtr4W@U9NYyOMt01OqsCjE3gCxa@F6aKI8KSZ1ugX3m4nA/1lCEuGPVdV3HgYHJvKZL3R3rf4GdZ3MYp5wMWuGiGq3Vz4/KhiwpfKNOBaPPDC1aTBDSqU2PmBt@lAJ/MOlCvk9Hdw23XGn8Hx0Dfo7WvWql6s4u1BvbAGhgDvjw8tK1qHECPHj975LasQ677A1yxNh4vrGSP4nNoD4fvg09kjZxR2nZvaZ52cY8rbtD6ILgzvQ0e/ufOwTvd47wDDStbzcCYQL/k2p49NiSyrQo6xIEe/l7FQ4O56L/rCNKtej5gJPj@XeHfqVv2ddsbj@nTGg8nLr0oqkRbk@@Sm3p8BQqtfbSdvvzGHrVl31H2l6fQFPhyFtM2vc4A94Zzyjb6drszMO/KdNvQPcs8VYIhH259L90VMWMy6SE6y0MT0OvMZKSXWtT/CD/7qyrdHz3i3VpouEVeWTZCR7uvpbF@2nH5aCiaWAUHhCOtke/RrtAu98rrienNgUaWLIXDu3xaAg2r8u4vklgpWdFWiDkb9hdPrKRSEtJRIJeMDAg86qpkF5ezRZpYNstfqzIULSXlKLL85EPQ7S/xodFBMzJuC@4L9LWwNmlpJ2cNJn33JsPkw/VdENHwtXrYgpYsR4asoc/SLf@zCs3aUMG9jPBtgcw1MW6dU8nfOqlC4dShpNsmfFrwgaqbrBxDG5pjl7@Z1Fs5FecvWQJd/Pp8IcfNbLky7VdM1@jxKRA03SUijmwHFxyDDCJ1cCYdR9CRmXPBizMuy@4DU5eGbB44CLtKbFm6Gmh59Yd9pvTZU6Ov45Lqx6aHazKXUAWR7LJVRHfC/tpEd82vTaBkq4gND2bg05BOdAc/2pbAe6L3zc6jhYoIM@kj2F/QyT8L5I9ON@vifGC6uKIpNNwyMIUkx4kYqa4FesOSkNfH7cMzKeYNiO92XBp62di6PZ7hprAZmW4bVjc9GmX1v6tUx1VrvW7NxPlkNJ64/md5HmjNVHQUenRK7u65CcCl18Ba2UAfestHqiNDriCF@Z3i3LhKGv/cHNp99nkpw0BoAyEMhfMlhPMAuudnuCDHsZZQIqX9ntOeONAhObxgr6FujSyTTMv0bh/N8TxcnBN8sTC858CNCMpjfMv3PxSCdLwcI4/vlvXnO5Dv6N@B8o7sidMx0BgeKxJVC/xUjZ1gkTFu3LDxWJTzqJbWsYfQvMAwXNpkOrY18SRnYt3aKxRu7RUqbFoqRMiAJb62@@R5MkoNtCj7LinUAOVv4g5nc9PKBQPXiMy0QBBbzUcXQwe6xEN@HNIhrQi@I842ntnUIXb90F6m7zybQQfy3goTMP/J6KHRwWnDO9N@aj@xLRt6ozEwytGhwbf2Lyz0WB4Roz3GzeuAn@6dyRwR2BWdEJc29LHRhvodzk3v0xdxwA91T1/RFdHYIOl/oelOWjGHbcP5ggb9IuZVKu1ihh4ZU9ItVhMMb4OS1@lwkRjH4xbayMKMjTu2bYu/idtm4KM@uZ2rQFdAr/efKJdxvf3CuMBS/WyxqAdnfJWI0eVnT6wqq2O07SF/37ImyTL5mgDdMQ1XeYxHGZBbIcckkL7cW3lI8VYeMleNQJI9012apF@uasxBqtMPWAI00J2OjTNhvuGW1TmR8wfuYNPhEn6@cKANiJ8Cx9I7E/9wxbuyNRy1R/RaqTBEavPQaOPmnzYd2uHp05uVyUeG/BMLIiu6wn3@AbvCRl1giWegjSTv7rYW9KhFrJpjehGnXjldTot1JMs0Om90HDWzCV/zsekFfyiz8pSMK8aqI82IRpEVnTa0L21Ji0vXQKAZGpI3cEDnV7zbhreD01SWzIdMRgZOMi/OwqwUXW13QIW1l8@nh8zVMST/SD/gJeHxflw@lLZXSp4IHv4PHnxVgU64VcgFJ4wA67p7Bh8yP3Es//M@FPjMdr2eOT2AfOMugFXsBIuVhyjw4S0DTRurCgG1Z02GfPShH1l3NeqSOibRqbWSNCR27RmSYZ1JdN7b9GaJbL63S9nG0049oyv5xx3gTIP0ONjmFQbzv0smUKO8ERd7qgpH7LSQ85d/LkPuecAZQN6yPWns0lcZu8/2Hx8cy2NXXdo/bQ9wd8QNOW7h/AStlIkMSX2hO5H5Tr4crWu6nvLgSJV2Hu/LGGAFvvmMhgQfnJlb@Kwc9/SPE9UVfaUWhL6Gt1xAfHT85HFqvhOTJXYGjj0yklHvnaOjNO40@erRUu9o7D1oHT17ujL6/q6qJpeQ73OLZgdXcc8lKa2CdGyANgrE@Igfv3KncNWxx0b3eDY2PoXOEzm4@57JF1YW8ql@ZvaxFbLySkRRQ2VluZBLRlZmg7JtOOF3VX2emmPklh36KPyzcjkKSg5Zxckulx5um/G/LsWwjL8S4cMiqZmb1OqZErSM/gBNiu7@fTOmquoqPB/pPahXll9ZWYsBls0PD@2z95hKNnzlRQqdJA@oSjLvXEdelEbAuhV84fC87wjG9splMLcBCJ0LSxv8uWHNdEuiuazbxIsKxMZFbbcG@dx4jwmpcIXPGR7wvHSOL1xSzxIdMibvSPjYiUTZ2Xmwf1eEQx@Xt4f6@Olz9kx38ayR2wNGc2y8R47nktEXEo5b4UF3K6dTuw6A0m6F1x8vb88VdqQ7XduaTe@ehKOtpti10xnCISy0USBjaE7NZX1Vh49rPVu@zOiutPkmDnu2IAdHz6DxAb379r9Q1UyGThjCr5rh1jtqJmjgLIEmfYbH1kW9jvdD1tBBuUUGh@RSbfSxMcXlKHw0eJlSv7R/K9zS9xWTq7uT2/xKt/jlbknvhh86sqycUW8BmL/Fj@Xl0PuxPTwf2PKO7hjukvXHSzN0W0HKtxSkHOHOb0oZHASliUXfvFrEx60L/mcptR4bnpMbD@y2mVtahu0eniXJnuCZ6Df9/eUUukPLW/q2v@WD25endz4xlib0RH@z3IM4zelSL2CCxmBCWyJuei9OkLZB5jWsvsmPUWQPbG@XbEsz@czGFetLk3xojh9OxqszCiwRT@@/zsUXAr4AVdk@d9kD3BE3l86XqPy4LG65@ypRloXjgXiI6KPj7YCoDo4ULZLiPBefPVtwxj2j3sFRxM0xptNVuq40XaU6LvPhu/kOJ1b0wGc37R/ZwXe/8j2Hrhycyp1IWKlUMrl4l0R0AyUei5pYx2MB12mzJIS9vGRr/gZF8BCDLY/@lkw8PQwUJgP3VAoEwqutQzK1mpovsy28wKEC4lCSUkQnOqMpSKvB1i/83YaVinrF1mpMrIjM3@8ZHrnKjw0FuHjgIZSJSacqW/fAZz3Yq8joBHx2yUjFAplOzWfAJivRXdtVfzcnZGn94tn@s92j4@3j50eNTPPK3@0ZFMKyILVgT/lH2a4IZffRBqybHyJMu4yHkBydzo@qmRuUi0HJrhWttlC0eaHELYyzfmFZikIbXhXpCvIniTw18gU5DJ047KDEVD/@XucK33tKW2ihijhokdKEOquwzLKExzqwoXXL979@0wj54k00FbyLBhP2z32FRti37a6fomuwu58gxb3t/cfPD3dZkME50ZybXW9QK@f5scB8Ez7UU8@kFUA1FvejxKGuarX4XhwQE5fjrEJblOlIXqBzCBZgBzc3@7E3WGKd4AMG42GlKP/1G8pVXMbFrEkIGw8yFYdkgeSJUNbW1tgxEAl7eLj/6e4hw/zvPiRnRBGCYMe4P/JPf9zlh9oHx5QEt/A4I2IedByEEN0jHWwcnu9tRpxT0x2vvouHDpGnHcTh6fXh9RuCQJcbAN2e0wlj106fStKBMPzuIP9wsCAhIqHgIGwcN8WDvhyXnZmuifuXMQ89PHdrkdhxqQWdNSezbbxoCK8z0umGBcj6xPL42Tb@SRgxoDQ5ZDlptk6Z5fcxiJGA8c01IPa2Ad0Jcy1QRg2vwr4ASsSxyQrf3y5J9fiNKAHoCpmkgTcaRgLeOKjLVU4c5d2v/DOlX2Vg9sD8Hd88zTwA2y/5th6Yf5mbXypIaDcP9prnJZohPIzPLwHPSIh/xH3kfiWLnykwRxyePxbwVWaOoJrOCOsYnKfA3xKw4zmcRONTqDQgN6gx/ywBnp7hNBN4GmBFUZCkUMSRaSW3MeXLqq6dCljIF3KqApmUzgKAdIx3H/eLcoDJZAWaiXBmjmuvoP/c3NxkIuo5Rq1Q5TWrrFsvs@KrMKPrEFY4H2DmGgziQJR5DPCr@9Gg80mpSYyK3CuuxpFxdW3olcgfey@0Wz4iRJYAZHEcGXgu9BSv4vKcWXC6ZRsvr4pc8bDuA5JU6JPIlBQFfxf@U9sD8oFGOr/Ehe/Cx2WFvAfEY@NcfhEdHSqJ9CjfbFnzzaPBXRJ@W5ORB3BQ2cz1zjRat@ILBHGEICriMvJtvGQn3onVVDhtMiDTHy4hZgvMv6j0V9AsL/f2zSMFE9cPBERksftHlo0K3R4UhiU0RcsqaiE5L1Iut7RIfon8ZKA4eKDJJSQHbApYRscwv7DH7vbO7v5XD54d3Tg2j0LGrwcDvl/fTJ1IcrrRDA3xaLEWq@TBnnL05MFeUBHzTBci3BgYv18S9baSzMdpEOR83f/1oi3L4fXSrc7xC74z@Hp@s9ptWaNIN/KhZj4gXVp7K@3RDprriWulZdjK52/L0hyeEgG9w7c/3shqInlx1Whu1k@sWPwmJSxpCC9j8gY2AjCduBvrChL7zcJhwcIrIo/xLik32hazy9uiuJ7F05tw97Vnn87PrfIdIh6R8gbJAIsUZCUIurL1HXAZfX66msavsOTnPEVPsYlkuJC5DeMRUMfBbZjIReZnQ/rHIg50dzA020JwehA/HjE4xS08GZGf/JNICv4NAzzhhH8/5rQylWmhTSKJ3I5gpdltJy0G8JICNGiU7p5NQGV7Zo/5idM0ofrQCEyHNrBf0BNJEzPYVycjCNejz6FBg9vAuSWIDJiMh1nlshRwCf@gxWkKj7KE9Bp43KJfcHnUzSemSXlgTLtmH3h7IpkGjvaRqjZZeBgjFpoOX7TiItXZvBZubYof46bWKNo/6ETO6TwDekOXQb80pon4eTxZaUL66B4/f3EWT4rLaIlOBvWPyuxePyI0zH5RvZ2T6J7fOoPzN5dxi3L5JpcAt@uA@RlWwXU35bI8cAW6vqyGkvuR5zwGI4gRid5IH7PExOLnf8mMrImThJWmg5GkOj9C0GKpFClU8CEPmVHMHpl4/53QrRlLKDUgAnR1rS5@3phj1lBluQlmSiTJ1vEaqh2QuPDgu6QAOjBEqRDYGpIQqBmQI95IZE7gEAf9ISx86BS1Jd50Kw@NAdqIEyo1q99jkWvFFiVHsVyu@BW6yBXLDKjvJjuUFQB7g88Fcj1g1z8aBHAG6q8sxOaM/CbHi1G6MZ6RR/6ZIpCdWOTYz@CoEQaw5odydgYO/hK7FrQVkA8qlefHe61SUhFZeDZJ3zG7OEbNT64OVTz/rhFopspC0HiVa3QfYzQ8Ba7FDz/Bw8j2qMGI11hqLIqG67f@zmlTVW@lej@iXwsQMocdgL@HqxWAw@MOg9UCS/yWM/uf/QzvFRYT66p62nLOUvF8pgovtZpnefbR@okkrTcytfvrOmhR3uvpCejkykbu4Zkx6LX3@8qJKLIsyynKRnxv45mpFV6@nl5l1dLr07FaaMivp02xVEufNtmzZ5@9bb1NitOz2WvxJEEnUbGdg0tRzaGaH6uU2cVWIRs7LeMFkvQHzxvS1E/ZG3hOewz/yfymGzHraG73MKwYF1ns5ATvCxaLoqI04k34JyCv4OGKf6Mu1@Wt5tu3yYaue9NZzjTNsdvtws8egASpJY@0e5V7hOpsNn9PYSf38BjUe8D6WZNfIB3jTyqVkJjvIDW4W3U07ZHbdNvo9ye7@oy7m7EJfvY8P@6Tz1@8eIGGF/SwN4cxHzaHGKRRaen5GNMy2p/@ZO0qffGstfmn3xwpxhp@DvDznasnaD5S8x@trX304EEul9Y0jZufff7s69vb27mH6fyzRn4rJ2XWNv/kj9fWNG1TU9aarqs2443T089ELZMT5T/9Ubz17NnXXLee/T@@8bau4qsIrzNWBD4BT5apYMR3CX4qyliM9Mq7n9ibGFC5GpvRXysWeqwxtb5V/G/fO3gd82J1TXnhwNeLvY4VSjFuBAPYsoHtLFaPbWKwwlVsptRqNTAW/9u/h/j1rwIc9JltwqueD2AVZrG6VKMol7F6AQyqpkG6/9c3vhHJIWcTNRLjguc@a8Aj5oqauNWEZ4OeTQHPfJMyimLd69vQj4E@5w08w1ZL99R7aDYNGz@WgWdkG95JDC9kZQf3GTtspFKpptyS4JFfku6uqtoJMAC2QFo09kJY8q3chUXdQjrxXcDvRYxoCoiK6IqbfQciNe7w4nq4F0ue6ot/7OdQiBXW7r96WK8DK8zWsxv1FD3sJKgAhRVLom3fF1mavYqDqtJovnrM@JGddTFT0sR0On2/hdYpolSaxuYIZBxHLLaA2Rib21jUKcaCaGwe5kPD7eLzZ//rn33/z75Hf9@n33/Cw/OsrtlTNiDeGTSdOjz3K5VOvS7WHfHiBO11oLdMpVQpKa2rk8QGcKrmIVMzH1/G89n4EaMmB3RykgzGQ2PhU6/ji/59G5noe83N96mHFgoxj3J3OEoXumB/maHUOKs3JRScalJDLeSbEqdHKiM@Zda4D9UkasWy2Kxree0Aqk4VecUN1l1mx0CDLECkLXjW4I/@4QmtazjmvEZua4EPhbr5rIXp3vkAzIq6oWWV/EeFXU2INRpK02iCIAvdqx/k/lplrVQpVDSldQtcVr3pZBjGMzd2pqqddrv9ptPW4WnrHV317stFuSRrm/pEn@oz3WtP2tO215l0VFWIvW2ssUPeDJosFTwnqTuf57Lc8o1ksPEnSfY0JsT@EZ66qqlsAxhpBl4gPZARlDv8g3Kw2AU8zbcbjbcbQCH11CY1z2Zd8nMJH7l1v5mSrq4aYK5W/f/Nemis0sNNULjmVSq1@bIuSY2X9UYKQL70QcocptyqNzfJI0zLT8z33mwySC@12dis2Tv0gyjwSE0AuLmQyfv3UzKY7kPM@nqTJVOpdUlaQ97d8HkUhG3WU0FhMO0Ei@fseMG@D0oF1P/V5lX9qrF5dbW5Cf@b9L7yv@B6tXnjnz7zZ0WYuX@TNbJaCeSbev2kodRPlBOf9ppgl5U6usjKCRjq8IVw0JcJMWidRkWIbbCNGJ6tlY1tCLFX7778n/F38u7L38OOnsGfEFM2UD8oczUBXow9sdgT/lgW/MMvsKILOjypo6PFXxZOISjKK5lV@ChtQi0VkjKywpbda@E@XZm9gqAM@QMTtVJBbKXUmcZim2KhSBzi52888Xj8n7zSysU4V6dxc@kr13WfRHI2zxsErmoZVVIv6/z8ZH6i/c8ve/7Jz696hNhlGbDGgOm5jGNDiEEVxCSpLsTqmyNcfIjj2RKqDme1z6Tn2xLqurpHsxUdrsfV9ndr5XKdD8WvPyPS2Xi4AW8V/nfXoBQC9ixC7AJf7df49/gN/rHjDv4dvsY/dvwG/w49/GNP2vh3/Br/ttv4dzzCvwev8e@Jh3/P@/h38nPZrFoV1y8IFSm1rF6tT0VCSTW2VT/5OV5JvfhPv/vNb8ZrtbgUp0P1cyqo/WqyCsh03Xj1flyI1di6uq5mhplORm2rbTCYLOOwzCAzULvQTbVUljFYZpaZsczIVrtgMuAvAyYz02OZPstYGQsCgi@YvFbGQ1MPPn346wEgB/5MXBrTVjMdBgkNUYKk27gQPJguWydCA1Rh8ZUB4r2syhm5YDbxDoOG@OrVibLR1MolJiOFyK3Gq5N4E0@71co51p4ZayevWMwF/aAaU05OFD7SAWUldFxdtVq7Tx@2Wgoyz5Mn9sH8/@BgFLXe@j86sJ8c2CMb/g8ODp5A06un7qeAvdy/XwN243@2YvXq1kmFuFXAsWLK5tZJPSuhuZACXqShW@oDnzlE@NbXToT4eQJFu3OU7qovzqtnVTKfB1YwtKrzAEEwbvC/8JwDYw6kuHN4zs7RQDY0nr84CU3coLw4P0E1B5Sq8F9RFqz/AP/m/7v@nzxnSZZoNJOJi6vNBD1J/EsmL64urvx3PZlI@JbEJvyhA9gxysVVHY0U6AJMjUSymby64m7wTiQ3OcA6JLNZp7jzcMBDYmGSlCx/Jf5hv5C0/5zEq0yfr1E4OZlmMslqOzikG2fc9EuaCE5W6SKm9XZDbf7Jj@gg9q0kBcrnqlV1g3GLltOq1VxgK5aq1VJgWU8kyjefemZLLYCwlsslk9UqWLYCsBmwhmBLADaw5AGq4eodnwte7B/QEeXAJfIxvBuAs4VEhi44wLty4mJFvHcv4d/Bu7WdvHdPK2cuL0OX8Ric1AWnVqtrOq0WumcvL8WWSEsGynmwZ0qXl2qmnFLjSdtJPMVLliCphKSyj7Q6pVoG5qvlikn2D/IAsPzmZiFXrxdyYC6UcPLy5kPYYOJ6PHYR9NzFJGeN8XVFrHI9FFq3iw@7uIpRtbNcPpkA5poE4e8qhn/cWS2XuXuS5QqJUqrs/9XWkqwOogj/Q2U7m8ptFDfug6iGf9OlD/Lk6oVRU69qF0YFBy2vqh3/ikvcGmzcu5ctA1pLmeqJ0Go93D7ebrVqoihirwovdCTuLuDNWmMn3qAqz5ebDSxh8yQer1TvE3mopTwDOvDDSXHoJlipTIgQzB7u@4fSC6o/lLEmaPTFl1D2BzjAMYbdOv914WFd1mZ9fFifmabJTDakhw0Z96d3pxMGsvnj@4ZWiotP6GKEjxB79nh7Z/c4rW1KLKbtbe@ktaPnD2IqWvNzO3ln0X64u/3w4DlEePZ4d/to9@P9T3efPwN3l53Pn4DP@@/5N2paYj9nL4QvnDe6YejGxDBa55PJ@Wv2hWm2TKi/4QQKYfcd5hotyPtYn5ejCr@O6epffKE7Y3rYux9@@90P/7t3v/3dd7/97Xe//f2ffvn9b8Pvx/D7Lv9@99@V8/j@6Zf/4nfe/dZvg@N/gt8fwu8nP/3y17/Bf2T/I/j9l4jbH/m/SDj@EwDWL/30y@/96Kdf/vIP4Pev/N8Pbv5@5SfLf9//1uofxvve79we5rv/Hn6/y2EFYb/7W9wNvzfC/xYP98s/ePdr/4H//4n/h8bffvdrf4Qv3/LPf/An/@XdN/@jppX@5N@@@9b33n3rm@@@9Z133/qn2rtf/7dqJvr6nXff//2//IPf/cs/@B/p/8f0/t33@X/3g3/@5//Ln/9vf/4H/u8n8PsPYPrJn/9HaBt/8/s/xP/v/f7f/OEP8f9/@td/8/u/@je/9G/I8Bvc8H//q3/H33/1K//5r3/zO3/5k2/89a/@5K9/4/f/8n//5f/z1//zX/33v/dX/@yb6PgbP/nLP/ylv/jmt//iW//yL7755Yr3t299f/ke7l/@I7i8fz7fB877lOtDXb78O@Xn74ONeSpAJ0Ddv/ju138BCPzXGHv37R/jOnr4rfj/saZSmB9z2/8HDNrNMqNPBkzw@9V33/4uouh/ABTBf4iv74SWBR9u@c7cAmj9zSWRfvGnX/7LH5EtZlTqNA6O3XVJK6U2QKXZKJf9LtsfIocov7AILQTgp/Qd5FALft9B3vbuh99496N/@u6Hv/Huh7@EHaaUK6e305J6x/wCBMy/RzgMWHifcBjwM0w/RWNCUuozsLHPfM/PPvtMaF0quGHj/iW4fkZO/GHcCzd0@F6BH7rjDg92yaJm35jxjeu@a5gy5QJTTZGgsRFIQfksm6b8DE1x1BK/4A6BphtknOKbXNF7KuBr/j83TgWWwjD8wYulAiMZ/Hh@Etwo5CGZ1HQaoIvEMsZFoQ3uQjNulG6uzLAE02lqCvouGCCFFHg9SLFarZbCiDWeH7DyrNVLjLKSStWg3Bibx0m3Sghi@oCgQMxa6pC1NmpTHjGF8OoBOlICOh2KqiamSrWHkGBt@pAhLAROYF@9qtVLtWkdwb3l@EhNUw8oTwislprW34K9RjAhnhB7@BayUqqlUvUSJoiF5NWTbvFKylPhqOwplvLrAL44iL11n7GPRLUktrh0iAjjofGdmofGgBAc/E9SG35x6D8w0m@DEL5GSfmpMO6/RYLoFpdNMQDAlSRZlhn8cM5ui90H7ykHlaJk4ZPiEFJEEUQBoQPDYZ@UkKL6TZEF0o/VNj74QWBYmPX1dSFWF7PigUyoUxTmnFZoFTkurELFo8LEQllEZ4OW1Ad5gfhVSn89jlMPccYBs49S/Hf//gb7CIpJ37mbwKRU1s7ZMQ5lM5USNYBft1PCS9BABKBTAnQpyNMaKTkpIZ1mTK7F0I8dHBz4mSCHlzUhBWSuZVW042zcZDKJQQxZTsvptP@V6UsOsm@Qydf/yuuIXLqklGlargqKUpWhE4tqNSoowOj49u1bqBVaqVLZB92U@YtWtFyJPMGB71cfDmfB1gstVxa4Xs7UQo6xBA2DwpNkSYEl2EZS4OubeSaCJxHXSqU4hQPsy4mNYA1TQSVywCHQWB0zGjxcWSzlk4HnzgHbOXjyZPfp8bjZZIJBl64arbFjdwzXTaDf9tOHfG27Vi4kY40Ggj6uaMhghN1Khtjf/sPD/aMK44X2qyBBGavSzJNfzLIqxMbjF5sxfw2HiBcK2eIRvivzsiW0chaixupCrGOgRoFTiqgGV1lVeOL2H9hTUPnTophWC6jGJWnglwlftycMj7vje@OhTeGKd3lzkzAg1C8kGphHI9RWQajX/dVPTBXqR7vHEOH4gKlaRhbqn7GpjAlKV0J9WBsaVt8brOMyIvEkI0bKtN7IpPFPy2bhreYKaTVfbK6tDS8kTPOEqu0C14NdgfVCwmJ8BR4mfEVgXwEneCANXOTF/BV2@wdVf5kTHiyT4GudRDUPzSwpnEBFc3DCOPpUx0DeoNVHfkJs7fPPPVavgy4t7e8JMWAXAxYs9ZHMrjyQqZ67E8cg3z5jXfNTE6@KkrumOx7qM2g7gI7Y1dVVDyDt7zGtrpGVx@ji@6pDLm0wX011IWZVKrW3aq4o5LRK5W1W0wRwEDYUXEu0BhRAU60bCv@rupBINltSgFWpogifbDYr4JiwUMEr5PE84poWPgIutpY@mn5Uq0nMXwSSoQUg5AMerO85LBP4FbmfbysIZIut4WIius@y6rfAzL17WRyUyOYy4ejD//8se2hSZXNcz2bUTWUMRh2MuU1FB2MbjPlNpQ1GE4zlTcUE46SeVTObyqQuMGGTnx3HcGt6TfSMKR5Vyd3EumsMezJuw6iJlIAmbvpnsdb9eHXcz2Lr3RruX8a9B4nkhdCvndNeOsGo9WXcBu9Y@lDo1rp2hy6mFbpy2@7OZNebDXHnwtB2anEQ6OKBh4nXB@PuvZoBEgUOWG1ls7lKgzXlsT3eErR8MdVQM9AV4E8tpbX0mrFVLFa6cmdo6M5WvpIvpbu4KcKfUtrKZyp9@bMnjx953vjQoJ0SW7kyRMAzZPC0h61SJZ9vNhqimGpQMk28L5MzGmltDRqnoXcl@PZsy3MlrdSEyF3TqdXi8a2sqklqJZspCVchhgTALRawLmDMFBYsjfi98FtyxbIt4BqVtJ42LwgJlV6vd7VxkZpbBP1C4jZAz5Wkp9sXobUqRcJV2CQtmXNPcNF7gPgLfyqtImr5klhtVOf2YkGsNq@E@yOja@q4P@Ikc3EzVgG4K4cag4ROmHBVcWzbq7SNnu0Y84BZtRAE5Bm6GSAnXoXJnWQwxYubyRUwEOCQYw6ImR/mV6c1gQ21nGvuAsdoNDeDY/6QiGMvX@p6vQ4VdpErarl8Lq9lC4V8UQP@X84V8iVoG5lCJq9pACBXLpWLVywBnZSuS/VaVssKmiZpWSmrSmoW/@8waPj//uE1@NfwDbGymnCMe@WfQscCnaHFHuOeW89mxzbeutBnD4zOihA7A51WT@44tuv@PcI80K1T7vXQ5AfUhV6PdLx6xh2Z3mBFiOfjEW6zN5x/NAi7ozZkkNgEBXgAL2do28sCFNnzZytK@SQ8EhaQwc@EheCH@x8/Oo58j3e3dx4JBfbg4OnDa5@8HyjPHu/uHYfWIvcNouZDEF/fffz4utX/5A6eH/YmtoM/Ye/geW7@Cp1wc56Qg2cxUOhMQPwXWkn0wmH2NZYvBgZVwCXd90B9vOcb84W5MYPGF3znoemGS4z5JtSKcBxsR9QZcrC2wTr8NAXUZ@mkI1/aVYtlQRgzyz5nxQzr2sOhjvfo9tbAcaDj1ioDRb4hXQONSZ/bzrB7bnaNNeEJ7uIqq3hnKWZCeARARpMOHSsCggCem9fFG25xXqc9nBhsgrdLr3CEDzqh0TH7A@jEzu0ggNDWdUaLiD7sgfhG9PFud/B4GuR2w2d4M7gQE0Txke7p01ipWs9UKvfuqc8csbyVFd2@Ud@dArWy59B6dGeWLuVFTxb3mNyK9c1G1W2OocYK6mklZ4/rOojqDRBsO1XoFrdy@Qpgtl7K5P/qN3/8t3/8q6xU1vo1deMkfpI59HUNYJQg8zES63zRTyYtQCuX8qVyViulS@VSLq8W8vm0qqVBgSqWQYbOqCW1UMqX1XQpV84C8ZXBN18u@oKjEkiKykYFwFodvFBzkxQJeQAaA5/UY28SepLF9NA@YaIBcUQBdTaP9qxumDXoppiaYdkiA4g667DY3t5OZm9PFB@gBRcz7GREsYuWfCmTKT4QRYN8dkoon4g2j1PCo4lEj1symQc7ojjhAPBUX1EcoGW3gKNOomiiZWd7bw/T6aFFw/gQ7JT7cMswsBQhmIUWEHUJwOsQGgTb5unkKKO7aMEk0WeP@@yAnyh@HGQHfQ55MA7gUVDS7W1R3OeW7W302aFi53lGP0HLNj2i6IAF2oEo9sHQd6AFimIbjNgaRLEDps5MBze8vBQPfrU8XRRnHD2IIFGcUmi9cyqKrcAdk/nUz00esVshi8pLfZ8sZfwTRS3INAbLhpasKOZCSw7K9ujRp/rA6xp9/swc/u1ASR89yurmdLK71/7443a/33Zm27sfH6LXzs4jkBRmE6fdb/sR2y14bIi180jTT0ez6w@Uer/VqujDpV6ftFo53brm1Zq1DMwhxHoNOfOfPiY0au2A186j1n192QQrAWwhIxjBt43PgxF8H@ht7hU85EXfabstVpH8UfCmK8WhJdLt3umR3nHsKtqntTXG4ol4etYoZJpV8mAjELEz1Su6SzyBbx1HSZIXs8a0lmnWprWixhfn9BLiyVTLm2J6bbSllvOVNX1L1XKpaQV3zNu9OItL6hZLqPc23rDE0@SWBjK2eLK1JYkNtbmlqaVKofhyYyKKyQq@t7LFCgTMxDOM4SvZKDa3ivlIlGIxpStapVhMVq8AHx707G0cvWglEueGfppMYnZRl4Yi8JvMZ1ROs9pLTNPTGs8XmyWr05pa5WcdsswNWF08WHfS8WyHQ@wDuOlWpkJ3pYtquSRC@oqSSCZRxyUlVhHmCwFffO349Pj4MwEZYt3X8Z/xe4CrvvXjRzsyqP2@DQ/ElfdQwbEdeQfZ1YIPP681cDoGEV9@BF0paDuBG@5LcuyhvDvtGGPUkgKP4JhD2T@cTj5@tADnaGCf85RxW3eVTjiyOgbD84LNLtNrdTDpXZagXDE9eU6deKter7VqI9r5DEUMYn3C6DDdOZh9l@c93GxO0S9wr47v0aplrqrt2jQ2BTitGpPUVyO7@0pLdapdPCb4Qe0BRq624NuuGjUDL6oXY2K1t2XVGJtYrt4znhkOHqOwf7AOIgVu4En0mJFcZyd0rf0OKgJXUt1h1jxnTyejBAjn7eSiU8SKqEl8LSjyBe0ow0ULV9VejSVeJquvweqss0RXfpDcylW7iQeslQSXzKveqx7TWCFXpfs7EwgJGhHhBsusJ2v1T0AK4oBPKxXIiF/HpwATUwKwZpc89OTYvKp2akOWkNiUJQk9uWq/1sDYl/jalESxKUmNy6ZQl6QXQh3aaXUW02vupE1ny7NMW9UyheoU3NRirjqAitVfTqtObTxxjOoQrP6AF984p1cBnYA1APPmMvHuF76R3JTyNe5WJVCXQxA8WnKrNq1aeFoVkEQtWwOPVCOXSYNuDK9iGrp5rZBWC@lsOpeWiugKfXw6nwZH0HFAuEgMEyJjYjozzchqWjXUdCLzyuy@SqZPEyC8EMpYMu3Zu3jxPbhAJSFVkhW@OkumtI0hg1qwmb4pEZkCp6hiwQDnAzY20wMEdWjoQ4qRTEosu5EYricwzPrxZLzbaFYqu9Px18ArIb3eKqSKmdSbZLKaWEvWXOO1UK8KdeQqVOrxGtCsPxbI3MmoAXUMJrWoVRqNNhaxmElnM1kondm67G@KdbGZzqwVVKiiK0biEeMcIzo6hkLO3G3cQtl7aEDVqWWtKsg0ipUtaVJZyW/kM3y4jMcUxj5bQ0yyxIkYbBJNxONFLR5Pxqs4Ur8m@kOzwMuIj8WBqcbvqVsiyF9iRSxrGGDOEmkfYCbIHUhgVwKOK7BcWYhdCFcXV5ugGCu0nhHER7ZGJkmu3xdiFcZADDzxj6VR1hj70GWSqc36S/49weXdAFegYyVBEqXlS4aJyhj7FLc8b7E4ZEx3Rg1NyzYbWhE6MmCOQVBQyas4ORHD9eNyHTDsXkD@NlN1PKnjEzab6alww9Q9xvqpdYHKHLs@Abld2@4fbgeLs7Z3cPz1BKRtsRoXYxfxWPwK/oTYfdqipPEtSiwW2aTEB@B/Ln4/Fo/HcaQbEPU2RjyC7VwEA1wVvOUooVc4R2g0k2@fmsOLUlbiQxTAoq6uYusK1Uyw5eOTVxoQRcyyAwfQinAoCDqrfB5HkWPKq7H7uVbKPtk/sB46ewbjO0BKuZZYj7GMKuGOimrFd82LrbVTFWgiK2ZP0zF2P0bLwMVySRM17lCNsVMprlb4rpHxUfll8WXp5ZPnB88P9oTYydrlmo0TBixczPbW@urXIGA8m4szdlKLTWu5qr@UrV6X1E0NT4Iqsgqw@55akDKXdU7WdfIoaODz7hd@kJtulsCuZVSwa1o@pdXr6obGkrHxuy9/Dw/1uNj9dPsxi@Mo89/@8Y@04t/@8b@m5WHxKxp51rLFGIREo1ooxi4uxhcXV/Bwv3ysGeOZyhWTYObTIGqsrqha1rKsKqsour5RTOW0@1ZV8cOqRTUZc6WYP6FTzMfcS99Ly5TAK5hxISexgFUS2z0085p6fxOpRQ03tLHwb9NwyzEhVnry6pIxsHTq3X7f1MikKKzyVmKbb6VN9hYnOd5Ka@xVrY6T5Cp4hnMAG7jdByfC4vWUshFnoP2weuOq2kwxmkUAlfGlYWxYJ9do/WSNlcvXnDYs@DM2XPrDSIGDC9bAZmx84YqJjaSidLv@gVGbBsvXgRQ2FMjZRjANwP8k6ST57hd@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@/V41EZSJarwQB/t@baJEir1UVeVSxAH598VbRAZRBZEQ7r8MO26wxVSsmWZj5DuS9Q5mik99CTfFk@pGsfRZ4XkEOfxYLbhAABnUcHTL06fb6Dn0GPeUEj2/Hc5o4M/B31vOTmJDR7XtB7DAWFMUcUuie6YAWQ3PtwSFwiayaxGjzQ/MoH7TIXMvh8mwtn8QPxcLQDL46Hmbmp7NGh7B0bKhQd2xbdPoZnc6C6@iBIoBH@QdH8WxPrHO87sOvG4oczZFLh0Yh5WOO6TQ3uieV4uJkd9sBVTfATZoZfZl1Rl2mlVmCCI0OuLJCcEmKRBlug0iMOG4PjRFk6cgwaJOUW1GUPkhUkzad8vXEBLoa7JnQ21iu4l9Jq5ybp6ZyjMeVS3YP91LxMxNiKIRh8@Pz6v6JWkPbPmVD89TgI8GJhRMnXAZKAci1acDs/AeIreCCDS2bZhnwTvNQ8CvCp8iNpXQk7lpilrz5zapriRbW6CV1PqaD182e6VYEv/RcCr4e7M7c4MwaOnkF7HLIcg3/tIpaHPehh8ewCP7pOzU6@EXGGYZxArTS4NQaNApjxzhjqNEK2McA0@wE5z9gK4bSfoU6AGp70LLwMDvPqeCpJZATp5voQNPzGbzFPmJZTcCA/Egh//gfgIFVX1uEDn4QFcvhel2oGJmG1ZGvQOscdcEP98v75IfxA@pGMx00OCdvtuaDw06H0qox3iwCSz5iwdaB9ExFXwPPAuRwSU7WEmIKwKbEpMhBh/GvR@fULhAvqbCbkNIMIfioBigkKgT3UbPIvRwCeDzQXX54s3/U3fn5uUznL04cUzZcvKvCxUu2lXHfBDHaVjxjNPZvBTTxNlgf7twk8Stq8Or1rSldel6@N@NfQei5NX/ZSyLec@PYOZ7hVQz9EZ3VhIckuURQeyZd49JJ@KtwOP1pzfRFQH8VpD@pFL9CIIwhmGl6lu6kAVi63TlN9867Vd/jjBokAIdaNAJHPBXVCSwjNzCZ414YwvaQj4Ze7eEpTbcCJJGP286T5iUMQs4Cq28fm1OIZBnnbNtx9FmC/JMYGgk4MSOxh82g2ycfMEI3wy74EZ3mtDFrLkSfhtGhUwu0JObgQUzCxe1A@Xmt6D/l/lPwn3L/6TzRINnGtMlFMnS6wuIg1eP5fUFIBDMLwlzxs03nPgQZZG@mchAYcrbgdgW/To1iB/jmNqjHWkAYQBNjQLiRUBovTxonTcs1zjeaKaUPxC4SIqDGAXSjSTg974ZmxP7wbDi23QUnC49thF7Jzzc6dQY@NXBawTKGFUSEwfFl4kl7/ZG/TIELBH6BAQLKYeCJosG2lzCT1fB8YPIEwmmIcxzzjDX8zDRJ@vK9fDcQlzjqOWKjgJoRQOgeFgmyCT4saDn8ZqKAO7xwbAgThJXoMpURnvgUb8YBk9eaCuc1VaqkSK4kKcgmoB3F1dr1ogT@UBWNa16RYl759R/N/toHZ78H7WJ57olgeYdRFaJNBdf4gQjhNxfCKqvXIvUKOVA29KHhQM@1y@VTv7eGZDaUQM3g6WAR3HO8bjkRqfxOktcP7SMULbESksKsVoMizmq8WfJ2EaCUIzyM5vrRZgEh@PE5AwEYmaXRDD/aNBptWqtxxsGmK6KdRzI5pUxOeRQeeroik00/GmhP@0H3gtXTBOkUFyGKAE/l3SiIQWOR4Z3LOOn9BZ5GhxOkfppznkNU4NMQithIZ53m0tQbkUxHmNY1AEiINwB0@SWHFeE6w1Ol0BbyKI7KgEdxm08GnFcAgRELrvITWxMhkZEODAK/mKJ@ANqumGoIokqDv/iX4T8xHTgGP/WmY2YxpLromElf@/tHcWwiZiMNNCJ9qJkcMmTUZJ5b/lGHUZkjhvcBD2yQ6trnNkssEbbBXZn4UZX20G4rIx0Xr@DVZ/514ONZMtAfcOKE3R/bnu7ZuVyFK00mkd2y9LnOYPYtG29MiJzaDLJe1zZcK@5BpXbsvmW6RprhgXqnhq92GP4R@kJUTvaNtisI/rAlV2MRNKcrFHVbLbyMtdVK4PK@ZCVcjEyr/ZA843EB9V8wReIDe/KBHowTdvsLo@Ml74aJR5D70Y7NzmniYOx74hDrNgMe1gH5H3wHIMEw155rjnS8MYrSbS9B1wYM7JHdB6lv4soCxr4Gfn8OGzOkj8eUlzTTUaWtRA6ip1aS6KT1pB/1kw@Oyj7REnoyjK8tAlhARpo513GMmHWWJNdamRyPFqR39OH5PYrm9@j2/JIWfj3PXDWvcc8PSzqbmEOAgPNsZO/OBhYd@Fb3RnYWshI6o1zFI7x3Fru0OKyLOd2GoNt@cLkH9JEObS7Ywox/ugr/t1dgEH33fatPxxuqj2bAb0a46DFBl9y4wQxoAoLvJ5NCbElyIWk/fM@0ICzeL7aHIgSIscS4LDyZFRrmGNRuN7xdIAB8B83jeqwbdE@LtGrcc0menLM0O9VWV9HDVtcY6jOjm/BDpiNwgxIfgsJG/Or9Co6MjpiezXW9BPRdydAXunFEOg9UWUEyevosmVxNVjyIGVIPjZRTDvdX4w/9b7BmHOKr8dFq0APi8RgOx56ZOPw5no1n/PDvIb/qxOejvP/hNYmHJdyNEMAD7z3V9DzZ5G3s8zARFuk9eoQwrLxYZDybN4CIRwHdrMMPQ9HdJYXKjUSqBbUsLF57sbzGzdtqPEIVAU3yqaX3I8m7iO69aS5CahzYnIXtfFgXcgMyLtrodBJRiNzl1hqzrRs8Ad1onM5a0au0ljDUMCZxOs8kdZvki6SAmvE@fHHA6VP4IsC@4bU4QQVlwzEt/9IwRj4jfRyRWnwXENIBSgSLHOV@NiKhhMAMwS@uwjQ7K9Ps3Eizs5Bm2AIWk4wEEjoLSfq1gNVzWxUMjZ63gjujF@rO8LmNbcNj2bqDoxUXcTNeMdMsfhavAEOOG/HKbgKYcrwbrzwkgxuvHJHhNF75BAzzthW/jFeCZoEBHLCS4T66@ywc7Z14ZSeRvBI8/dRwg3TleCWsUwizxa2EEUAFlhukRpxis2y/mJ5jQMdGQmWaIcW4aVSfaBwmTb8M/POLbOiKC/TEMc4NCsxSTF3oNCI9Bk8Huo3gCPUlLbni9@a7B3u06CkMgsmkQMeLxiHwIIbH4ovMiGcMfWlGA76QQeSbleU5YpGe7D2z46cOFEqVvJg@YU8meaCbIP8GBG7OE6Hbi/z4QX0tguAV@H75xMir8nkjO0FylCOck00uyRYi9VX8lkJhXS/mxa/9aA3RWPdiILziPQjCa4nARng6yHA0OYeJje3xIpGQLy6xN6NxaFCON0qk3mvRiCv4LXOFNzn7JUPGEG38yduKE4mHWVtgQejZyDR5Kwv7BeLF6DXndRFJlTc@yEKE50ALNzqndDPUQ99I4Ti7SVNfsaobCuLyJIlzLbJJiCzj6VMT3eOph8rrLp5J9WHqaxBzimMtCQQQiRmmwvmr/QHyu83l90CgDpBwLYFlgvXyrvSmeH1rL3st58N5sjcrED3T7GFyqXAUpjBHOWgHEcn8Nlq7IeLjkg8u5PNEQ@jXpP0AbaFOcAferusWHBZKCc7ZouOpBo6n2mpE3ZRIhmdyILTImJIPhxc8zOm8aLfnlRd8WRWjD41v68MPrmBnsYKjlYfwqADONZTzVu5MLFrlMm/bwLa5C7JUtcI4I6fp0rCa547A7mnqNpy2BYeD1uHDg6ePvw6dbrFYTPp99GyeP2y1ONYa9uMcMq2gDvuDJWqLlsbrW3CyG4fj3YHteGsnlniDl3BmDcKADqkE5Oe38aTPyyL8/FrbhXg8bASjPqzTeTPQF7gSijo6dtmmj1cPEGJ4iQ3dBxKIt4DvNGlrSbqopNWy9JHRalH31Wrh4qVWy@/FsGqCGfHkz2JrysR16NJRfsvOuSDQMQvs4QF78Wj7mB0/2mV7z3c@YV8/eM5ebD89xh32z54/eLy/w@C3@/RolwkLSyvxRjJUKAGvD42OgddMMi2TyTGCvGOPZ5zvJHaS3P1IH7FHdsfAaapNVx/dH3CLbBlencfaBXV0hmOYJt1ANzI9XG9BV6aBGovCTZe2BeKCfwZh26DTjlDnHdlds2dCWAF137FpuMFOMjY0oQaB3wabjNNcSMLb0WjpEN16iCuwziG6DuFx7gbA6Hz9FaIYQ/Dr1Loy8xEXPh@MwePdwydHDA9r2Dl4@nD/eP/g6RHbOzgE67Ov7z/9GPC5f3R8uP/gOXpRwCcH/09x17vVxo7kP9NPodgkuKH9jwRCYkxiwCSeJSHDn@TmAPE1dhv6XmP7ug3YSbhndj/sC@x@30fYV5l3mE/7FLP1q5K61bYhuZM5Z3JOcHdLKpVKpZJUqipt13ZqWxX@IAgUcgpRFH65Cof3opBDdqZK81ecfOf61P3RW1LrjRW8ummwg2SoFq66kD5BoxN89lsLJecqxPIFTpl8VKAy85X9V@9pzlf@bzjhNEfBbH@QOgr5xr75glrn2miwbNB4KzkmLGImW3T5POJyrHBph1/i6AoZfvaUAc5GPK3AV6kt2KhA9y1BGHgsG9BU0QOCDVDGYKWs@LKdhQVvnUFuUG3NTg/xMqU2MSLULyj60pialBymmLaVAVA4NdS60AcVS9EH4nv6sKyrHQ4kg3ocfZAM6ol8wFK0BtsRtaJzXA33riCe1ap8@OWyv8PHwupp9GGzwbvYNY2T9Bt3aUNFl5UhJEWHr1QSLQ9f@9gIm0HARULOj@uGOh0ZGL5cdEcyUY4S2baNcqZI2LRx1KDN3uT@WKQSN8BOqNEehipTdnPqEMZBfjeQy6zOO42umEDFpjvMe2oN0X/KG3r5EF0CxW4i/R4zIC6gS@IRldvWq0L/e8tRyc2pGhvaRpIvYjQmaN9CYHMKgX8EDAFKXOzRaPJMxT6rANNra1bOhD3iSOhtf7fzEzu3rpp@ooC22sr8Enz@7Goie4l9krFTZOyoiz77A1pW8lFmuzegMc5ila/NgRRsXvT6w0D6MJNsAZ848TRHuTGxUW0/G@Lq2kCHyRq7va5V6Rlx8R21nhFTfk@tzPFydh6Jr/g@VeJ8moTF7g7oNM561751dubhEOnGh/qFFsJ8Vg7l53jImMj604llx@8K1zCulTe2N0@yv//s4S5GEQtyFaoxOsR/YkzURcODz/nYYHGAdZceaeYOrfDqDKW1DZ6WlhjlBhjtAy8C2te9rJeiNDE3nv4OR5rJ7/zx69eylMpCMun7c8OLTCzdPHVsqvS4zKnSJiCW7CRkSdZnzBePYUby@iWcZ9ALJaJIF3IE@/aJG6q0CDGtO7tqk2TRF4Xq7o7gu2qDLSriW5bhFGP3R/5TZrO8tOHmY4MSZZEzY0S0ZyAXXdcyS@H5agrc9v3gSH5/P7i1e7GT6eEPQdu@F9ofwi27dDcsmZYsWN8P9vd7wMrk9g@BpbZ7dwOWSXIaWsTpEXN68@nImvb@Gn@e6jseewQGcy80KBFQq7arLh9Rm/DUGSng2mDiBdHB4XZ1f1@lZH9CZUnuYcvQ0mIQsB@od7G1bdBlYZeLFk12TGlZPJkvCYs28@@@wTyTeHeICr0G8TQ9ImER3yfeDkYi9fTMwksItr5ngWgol8Tui5FB4bEGfEt7QEI27jSrgc7MZqZl8glC2whc082TtbFtw88W1jJ34/rNwdgGZNsENc7hWTK7/z7I@vi5qUcWWIgchAa3aCVN8w3tEw6o4j5lzOWSPXhPt5guhZG9LLDThnYw/CokV9g/zlDMSLIIl7WwJdb14lijJuvjebPMYYNETAMNWHrqRLFopgQj4vnLut2hbjzpZZJTEC0ycSHjS5srqPjprZ7CmBrRPFmOFuT2WJtnbI4NlqfQzmrYpbszPYQt9OqkeJisiqTtvVVl/zlVySyRqMnQfGZjTCJBXl1Zefwt2JOtMMWzPwpb5pBJ@Tm87NP@PgYZjkNW7xPn1t56Jj1mgHtIJ6b1ZsBMFKSlzow5JdF2noxs/AgX0QsRMgjWjjsuJ2t11WgCt9nQZUayoXOWqTZYQzhqqIyaKerf3l8dBPI363vwx@uTwYZMMB28hVX@m94g9GOvPCuAi/UJLq/Jb/5g0OVs4s90CSgZdmO619mOve3E4FVahUQ@b7Nb0tbeSWJ26xldA1fC6sUcrrWFdq80qd7LFkt2U3dqu1W1yEEc2wldZGqQci3Z8yDo3ocAy2DWS2D6YB@@h@Fz@k84eAYkkYm9@TJMG/ebuDFFaNV8zJf1aLNQLVuLk73fDpuNLuJ@eKmHoUp5j6gga2GrezvuLM16oZQoT8iF/W6GSnmpbC7FRekbFLqAlAQhvYnv1oQFTw1jKQn3mvMe7KNwsOWPRHvGlpONfHGtsPrM4dZ1vaF3efzs1FtsllOKJt9G9zK8Gty0fj3vXVy3VUf1fzkbNceff1Nq5Yl6THUtP5JIusXVcp6Dlz6lv2vqWYE5VyP4gqMC45rVnNw/qdSCivfhpQdKrgHhTfNzeEhMcKlavDRcCBe7YfnyePW03C0XSpfH3dMSnPyGS@XhUnEpgw@PaBYlGSMn88fDU8ypttbV714rhLLk@wu1a4hi1xD68qYxCHq7lbevEto4LACgAtO23qxQlytt52DNBt@TXNe/yWg1mafAsQ4WSM4cewUV4Q/P@mSoY1oBYUa94tFqNhzx37HrzBVyV/1hj1NMTEOwlvoafHXmjBtTgTUKlOU4MJEP4V9AcOI8GRwMydexWFFni7JcK8J30rVAHKMki8PUSSoFn0Igqn25jk@dMOc3mhdAAnc4f@Vian2db3QmVgtzrMWDKUdjwA4ThVM84gCEfvp82oAqeOUestuHQ83HexEP8oV1VEP2k2EDeYdXikiB@bf6wv5NXH6dCCCEn5M1V06rOPXKixaS4jvIygUENktu/HHMALdK6ZQ5NBawpb5yDJwtxZlGqFaTib7P3YCcQiv6p1uQLfLbVDOi/K5kZ5LwObV@C0FL7lJO2sBPJy6WsYplTTGT2SLF3DepAU0XbY/e@DSsxmrL73QIaaHFXEwOPLJ/r65/Kao/PEadpxHykp6dSs8m0nOSLkjFuXI0wceZntuZUukvcb5blYqzeVN1lRUvXnLU080cLUnivKX78oa5Ya8exJk3oq4UrowS1hMJWSvl04zel5QHiTIRg0fpx5Ku@XtZ93yEZSLvy2T9@HV0B/lsPKttTSa4NNcNOi8cff2vTgGbpYiaSklxvjBQmUFV1j6YWpzQCg56fh62G@UYylLRSBweM6mN9ZepnF5kvMhMoiFejFMDa8YYsajEdS4x4UbssEj1cPIDCwTDBKMpM3I3TOGxLjy2wCLXA1OteEFODXBq2uQQL8Mv8iv@mMGeRM7kS89OnBPMR9J48W5OEoiF7oPUbDIlpQncReSjbtQ9s0hc93gS4mwh8dbSAkd1@uKD3YYa/EEkJ2xBYSTFFN2jFE3pOEPRsO9dXYjEW@fv@UXnVYPW2P2OP1IVbDMa7IXlJBzch344DBEAiuPYhFf9fgenjrzgu2EXah1LZHkFxy0xRGtmzzk1WPZIfg9P2iGdCuXUHiDfwEAkTgivzs/hTAYP2N4NRCs0LsEw51S6Y1Fo0Jh5vCxu5r5C8A0WwJ3g3EZCek5GDygd9htNP@fQGi2k1Y8jTW0H@qJN1qfDbwQhxmhKe@44f74Kmr9uvcJ57tNi4XHRItm1Pg4u5B4/iR2siEgmYRnhAVeKTxzHOhtuytlwFgA9tYuJ/j3xpn/td7u@U6EZgzOGtGgN/cG138o5zr4fHQIDLlgZJ5Pww@5dDZqi3KFFV4OYEV7CoSfHYcRh@MX8LMfFTT4r8xwcWsWnzdTV10ELBDQeJ@0eTof5wAJhAoQeKHTpD4koi65KosRnzxoXXrtcQhFF1ECcE@tsIiJDtzcMmtQzrMlyOgRKjkHiyrqtCUyovmanAefg3CwE4B4TU8AgYI6S7sPB0YfmfwgHpRtmztgbpmfyJP16PFZouPuDgKRvTGDuFS5m4U4dfPi6dqAO9nYOP1T2q4qe3@3vva9tV7fV5kc@48ZBOUfdVa/3dkm6RKfpcmq@Rx9SlQMqmeIEp/L2o6r@9G6/enCg9vZV7c273RpBI/D7lbeHteqBp2pvt3aPtvn0nSCot3uHarf2pnZI2Q73PK7VFHPicmpvR72p7m@9ptfKZm23dviRa9ypHb5FZTjVr6h3lf3D2tbRbmVfvTvaf7d3UFVomLNdO9jardTeVLdzVD/Vqarvq28P1cHryu7uREP3Pryt7is2ErBauVklLCubtIVFTdzO7dp@desQDYqftoh4hOCupw7eVbdqeKj@VKXmVPY/ehroQfXPR5SJEtV25U3lFTXOyXyDKtQvW0f7VYRIAiUOjjYPDmuHR4dV9Wpvb5tpfVDdf1/bqh6UlLO7d8AEOzqoegp3CXLVBIOoRen0vHl0UGO61d4e0pxx9A72Di518gciDGFZoaLbTGCYQaC1RKS9/Y@ACjpwB3jqw@sqfd8HTZlaFVABFhVbh3Y2qpCIeGg3U72tvtqtvaq@3aoieQ9gPtQOqi51WO0AGWowyPhIrEOVHnGr0U@ElzwSszqGcz3uTlXbUZXt9zVgrnMTBxzUNLcw2bZea5rnEIjXUqIEPegMGpe2YqU9/enaRwTKaY3MbB1NFDFpa2@7SjOyjmeVihOOaNZZmwilZKfRTBMl0msiZE3LP7s6rwfddg8@plExUXxchucers1xcefIiXPPrVFav8IF0ul6/X2lThvdg3rd9b6nZAKNb5XQavD7crm6jbjSADtvKH6ePxe6rycItfFIH3SyoR4OIJBTqP9ITN8al76r8vmWr4vBeR@AjeoolGOTCxylkGhkZ0dclhJXyZoJfg80O3DBjAGfa9ahJ4VlJGfqhfSn@zV@kcnB@kDSWdRd@Tw2sYxG8Nk31UglHBKB/@iIBEGbq8yFvv/reaZgV4c9f@6812tlXNeU4bxD2geeZ9xvFD/zzyeKZyfLM7J87KyvCQjNvpuXMNH5syaZ0v2SG3DLMvhTH/KPa7CRmA/QmnJVrKzWSsvMIykOiyRP6dAWcK/gTsaa703lp9oH7OYKy09KE99fR99lbMFeEJFqacI75nKn/PP6VDLQAONYHESSQEfIyOetMsbeJMp8QxkvkOkmaMHyh@bqC5/ndSIJLWSvGh27TszGg2BkY09y@NV@5c3m0c4OiU5g@2Rt5elqyYnCbv3kye9H1MPhZDnqWJ/mcVqncZI1SrZo4cMjxQrjHbM/M3A@j4yI1m46jT8izkNkt5G0ZIIgQ3ND3BzUhYleygcdUooDcDxwDL/OHJmaATKJprpozWVjxEv8Bq2VmAe0MUtnzL02wh/Ajoa/GeJRgzQDaRbjALvEubS7YLmX2jGmory54cA9yJJLGT6WMG4RDVjVxfaz8K7lN83bVi@GYsqI8crdziUJiQeTWChjV9GVkf2O44xoBTBHD6MvP2l@o8ePOsAdh7trhMPK8IDIuBOVhJ46VkbrRh9ryKe4OQNB1UxN6wpaflcjxWNPq5OjwCDWaGBUcMUKbHyTgEtRHJHJKtkC9uWCq74IpyJ4B@CUNMfqd@LcWc3RUEomfoh@N1EplMCKgpwI1W6iOhyT5WMUx8KQM0GmH6IHw/8X0mQG/HXacRL0mFpWEMDvoiRDFVrR9pWJEtyYgwbrdCOmpv3pYwzm1u6Yi6hh@vRmJP41RALdO2Pz4SOHPWxnZhAATA7Fhj1@I5O0iwZtnV6mXF0c5yTd5mU/o/RcYaaKKbjZ1VOPl12eOVvBi6tc0TVZFe5SUfVSNm5nPOppyzSxlVcPw5SAc038j/wiK0CiAc9ceiFWq5OcVdCjzMgBHWrJmnBaUcQkWpbe3nlqt6isEJkJ2a9PvgyhCPQG8JluJ18j0lNinpuMuMgzsTrkKHgIGo5tMiYfHbLujA0xOz7gPGyxMgQ3jQxvMEF0BDqH6ouhqcxDNhRBJbHVYRxnEOLWzRFpeVq9ibBnzSQ4NML@qCvR6n3RapkcOQnwoTG03eVz6k1jTCh3vq/ZwmL5xYOeB9tFVCZqCV0et6o0e70BLR0baDfh6AVjN6c@aKWD3w2vBjp@Ic1nwUBrJMyin6rBskl27zzNSKB4Ri0MhvBWaOWYP7hJlz4sRCU8ySi7qjLEvIZHN4zSMRgtFVVmPU5ZJ5pwWFIm4rpaVV@/Si4hqA4Z6jMFgzDaXLDNJteDc4do@N30Br9i7scSqNvyW1FkUgsk6wKlk2pdjvHYHErT@72QNRrUFdCARJQoiiItMlSlOfqpZidt15SKo2Midim35I/XEzGpsZaiimLG1bUT861mqTNBpWUdGjQKFlpcXmFUZm24bu/cjHG00OSxtUqddCOR8lwWEeWHZumIJ5Gb0dNHPGklf/lhiNFDX3DGrZegQBhrVpyrTss5xg82BR8Cf9CydaK0kmk1@lC/8dan12VeNKpDHfav2RiG/ph2AM18MMozjHrmT72Lbn2r12mcB72gQfs0xHoficTD45gf0WHng95NyBcGcULLytQax88SX0bCsOE9OpcsWaG5wqHfz9hmCsPBuHIhYSJYcw4jwPg6T@bv/mSMtKjMk5W4kJP0P2V7vKJburPs4@KswnKiDwBawG1MWFCID@mQHZMs59PSVIaz@zJYOJ6prGq4d1jsJTB@RiTiY5gExgaZKbMEuxHYmd2J8XFr5LU4BuEAgZb8bR/33YQZ/uw1cEMySZEXsBR4roprBauonKKMEIcQD@O7yb389F@MPSHwA@gXH8/illmMwCKubaIthbJf0VFGCRc2DwxYRrMkJikWnAddy/2Qb5oYTUJNJo/vogZb/tCiSIfZm@JKjMgMbXxwr12mTiKnPnYxqSyoBZfjdmAJUhlmCnczrP8t@1ke/DjEFc0ZBNOWhpyxkL6LVE2iEu6gnTCvtVGWmMrfHjHLy9/baxMELM8yObPuQs6kzMqFPVACmV9xrNUbkDBOTVBPm3oshMNef@E7qXen7JgZmW0WrZuu@01DYGG2Mk2Wiy0mbXmMx3HJmcRngmmSFGNLM@IhbF/5OWLzSSKOynWMt3J9/A063EWz2G4qmlSi/m7J2MekeA2LXjPRREOKcUeQ0lL0/bhODa/fLUE0TNle1Vli1CEy6mN5tEBNkCmi0vdTiLlP4z5BjxZRDvW2iHZ2/9xJ1EkjORPy1CQlglyCngjcDqdNkkv9NowvECZOVriRkIoWnCNvzEd5xewZggwjQQBiVexnYz2UaHDjzprgI74doJ2pw1qoCElETxu2hUMU9D8iGEfl18odbfFQH2eLpyWBNIog0a6Cc90Hyfib0@txfcRQpkhBQ3wGKaIWTcmmi@9v1Y@2hfIRBCnNydrSt@ChMa5aImzoj51UH2ENHFelSyZGVHIg1Fk00FigXcp5x5ftKlZ/wUA4HtYNehjRBkI@Z/CzpEsgnPdqIaI2ioxaY2RxNblltLkquyFFYoaSd5BfD0VZ6vLGlQD4gjGVLxcJAsKaMvY4FODQOzbnJRDVfUQFy0UMS/rIUVFjO88Z6SCqzvBkxcpRmJXjmQ0jOxMILSxm54kRoTXL7CwxFJroZuJi5Xg6uz1xDloQG94XilNX6F5J0jDqOSEgX9lccGOJclxUXkFzMCc@WXETiRF/c@qzgpVamEwl@kQYHmeLk6lrhURqotrl5WTRREmih2vXmkgkUrg2wpFU@LF/7JpihzyPbEKtTUZilaHts3GlNu0yad@W@yVU6@yUbdYYBp7tGW62X3W5YiURlP3@AOxqgY8MELv9h1trLFMNJvquAI5LZ5xdMrIh5BVrClM9moWdrom0FwUoMHvaXlu9P9zZSYR9PRsbQ6NLf7BSKBTAxGd28HtjWw1VUtDLJ3Pn21edTr5/86fB@7M8y37f5ysBnpsdtE9dQoMizPUG53IzBHCgrMid1Y6s2Otftdv2FQw4oUTnUbdJTh0NQfEEFERGL@8PWQHEIPUE@zMaiPb9rKLRd9OQhaaGYo6hqDRMgq9T5vSMyIMPbdhnRydVDAyC2Vgz0bzllje@YAbBzSbcWRy@2P0SmyenXvudTs9TH3DlMCIFzN1OFtjZsQsUJAtOGNm79yrkeLSe8q@DjuVXjCw2rwOcmZjMPRMmLjxi4@/759VRP5M6/pSiaYWavIRmLiE@tadS5ylXB4v/DrDCh4T2d@W@bPQzTabTZGaa6vUIjp8Io8dFb@beJ5HFZZ2Yptm3c4Oos9HNcbAGarrLawETy567l1tyR/aIuKmTUbENGhYEhsYJMVe@rwRczf51YvF62G5/n1TkawCkY/@QRJSbUH5MIPIZAI9APfyInoii/W9ZGtY7EwFFZIGDyzqm5Q4K1FHAcR42y7/dZCqViprvLy2pSmWTHrJZVdmsqG182NxU2/S@ifdH5eWVlZLI3G33C33cNB9v1SbBYA3nUvNisE2vlFaG3xistdHF8/nyvFear5fXN0ph/riyCbd@evrbv//n3/7jv/IV/fI/eNnkl@NPUaZcLpefb36Zf3Rbwvvx9unC/NnxfP904bwELvs7Rw3v1YbZRmw@mhucOWmZBayvbEdq9tkcfUYXVeYiwMvG4FeSLs9Vuhnm0/prKDdHsYxNN33ruw8/yjPawptLBya38oREmoCOoY6n3mn6MMCj@YYoSbjADlTKy9mKUdwjHEyUITpVSetIPLxmvfbh0xJHUoAvLs1Y2aAb@l1owK95zSvNc5wG/QbDuubf/Kc34flmb6QWTzJqsaAWPbWYSvFPcfUZfXXn8wG8cyUbbQdSKY9S4qMFmBmqMOCFHu8f@K6dCXI7zjxf2QNIJkwFZxYvOC/a/bGzjFy4Fp47c7hvU4mKhA@ZUCT9Zb57S93yhXLcphKuNrxQqOtdDFdmnahE/YslUCMUQ4C45kshyPMeVYmTPvZIxlPefNF97fBtQgwYZN1/tcPjHh9oLprvapvnxF4K1xyx@bx8xdxYEmdoRhspUn@MAB@oyHaywJ6EC@kFR6y8rVZyM8UL226fZj6xdRj7Q2ObLoV@VxYTiDW3Tbj5rvZr0YbccryiUkF0vGJVlZq0/VaOVeTyqjMM@tpdgWvHgPoS1XYrIwk9yoAEjsTsfz49wlhRYCJFTXSLXJY1Vq0emi4joatd06mD3ZycHFlEyH/K0Nj@OjG23Tx7iRh2EB5gpCJTvnYj6IQ66sqAiX3eGJzhdsBGmy9UG8q5GevzcMXqBMa9doR0jiGzyXk8nqkp6f6gcX7Z8FT6be9w0BjXaNqilc@wmXOphQjBBCQw@HTVs5pnEJYW6S5hikRNYcshXF7QGevr0aRvU5HPCbrUDAUddgWDIMFOTEn/a6KvJugYc/Uf6AQb5SnhHZ1GahHLkheWRhpSynab4WE2NXQcU4M9dqKBk3IE1WhkGl7Qha4w0V7ywS9J8g5iBOi6U9oLULsirD5D/Zidzv1uIzE59TuOcfTPl5TMixjPfBWlWCM55nLUYnzjHbCideSnZBQImZtMOCNnLpOZOwn1dW5pex7hIN@RLX6@oYLoAjq@wIw9Q9RRNxBhOTFDxXdg5FSNLf8JQrvTOCf8xjeNMVjxJJ158SDvHn866Z4uZk66X08@u4yJFslmls2qtD7MNhJLjxWaGfNe4tVYpYUm1OBJN5nhpKvEh8UiASGSzxx/yp9@zRNCJ2lcPH@SFoIkugyY5O@vLw/w@Sk000ks8mlnzl10TednXhRdRXMr/6IP5YMrv4SF2VSymp72OYM2gWI/3d@uxOUkzK8tF54sF5/QTujcH2UH/hXm22x4deaPaCkRYjtLU8/J5wQ3JAhxOwobJfo4onbKtSbiexJqJyUtQvUw53qciK2oTE54gvITlTlcKlxc3ChPA4eP2PB7iljO5OVYUGI6aHFfBvNn2LtEPY0Qcm3SO0Q4ElYGYiPCKtQsIJvLV@7iUNcMlwX2c8qpLcRuZSDUvfm0NVt0e92sXqy5uYUSFtHwmumsFdYKk2N0aogmRui8XkwtPFDFjRdP//rfe7@lh@mN5fyHAf0O07@lV9fS8kgP9PbYvF2nN9LryLZ6mx7naQ9Mj0//@r9UfuNPBAcp43X6s7FiYK2O0xvZMhf5mt5YpYfi8jLV@39/@Qu1YV52bLiLdb7uKUasZCiy1egy71K6qqGVsi1diMUKO2YBhlgY0t6cXmAYNVpeK7CaLq2tKq59HfnK2KPoKZ4Ns4ZsKiSaDGNPQSsjKVBGBVkBaUwo2sqy3TBmG2DeGE3188Pcakg7gJ@1OUdUZWS68TCEydC8bIuoAzNSI@3n5WGj8CIVmXc8TxmbkpJZQmJrp2Xt2uPS/wM)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/259gf)

Perl 5 with `-x` [flag](https://p2k.um-surabaya.ac.id/perl/3045-2942/PERL-HASH-SEED-in-perlrun_9_p2k-um-surabaya.html) searches for the first line that starts with `#!` and contains `perl`, and starts executing from there.

The code:

```rb
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
```

`;` is for SILOS, space after it is for Befunge-96.

Answer (score 2):

## 341. Windows NT4 Batch, 15470 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a 5    z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S    &rem     / \            mxf             a5 >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                     ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11p&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] '4o'6o@ )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;p
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__





















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hatax@#8;>0::&&1Pr"9?3"sge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogr61k:4op>a>std[]!!c;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1*\'\0C0ullrlot   
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSSbfUt6pULalu3b4UiwWSIIkrEmABoESWpIrunt1et@2Z9fS0He22x7fdM55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKq8iNiY2MhEUjk4@TJk5knz8nHQVt3Bz/7WQwv9swezvpD22Oe4Xqs65hnhiOzBzN2XzfdvJYVBIy17fQnI8Py3IoQYypjQ93qT/S@wXrm0DOcNHMNg7WNoX0O4RpjmxNr4hrdOrxlGbOMc7ZvdcwuQGCefWpY5hvDgbAcYw@N4eXo0mMdezTSra7Lxo5peRSaZ@yZDi@9SeeU6W3Xc/SOZ9oWBBUYe24N9VG7qzOKPnYMnqjIAFTnlNIshpQYe2I7rgE52B3DdW30LIOn7pj24@2nH1@Lr2bYxzogNR4a02vZqyp7YRpO93oKjX16vLd33TfLPpFsi@3dREnNse2JZ@971@Hn2XbfsHSmyWVZux5YAGJ6xrCUKWUWgiBsz3SgFnW/tlhHt6BWsM42mDEaezMm8XrWh8OwDl2mu2ziTvQhxbMmo7bhBBFdT3c80@qzc9MbMG9gumE6iu2O9Y4hdY2hOTI9o8uGJiSyez4UAG112akxO7cdqFofpm0NZ5DQ6Jg9E5MEeABAvBLewOBwRvoMKtPyoBEwnbmAxtAIoCWFGMR/aLQnfWZPvPHEY4Bb13T19hCAtmesa/T0ydBLszaEATHJ/3xgWH6jBXAygDi2OVZfTAg1Y9629W6XZaC9Ah6nBjOBaoRWhWWz4M9sB6gGsQKMfGDUfnkZjSnUDVR5z66wfCYD4buhD2KrD13bR2YRNQy0oE9SnSHcZ47dd/QRUKNrEE0/3X/G3I7twBv8MC7vN7eB6ege29xk8d2nD@OsHlaL7LSFsIpq7AKqIBYEsjN9OIEWEq0JG@rHCVMLWGXxtXiFxYEsWoblciwH3bPEtDwQSc2UwQH9XMuq8CswrcRyKvSUfDyN@fQcvW8ODQ6lj1CK2MC1PNPgnsmxrFriMfv2sMejdSizIsuWWKHIinlWhHuZlTXIDUHnmFrOw68AP4BWBlRU@GVzHNC83UM7xba2w3r6yBzOfOgEvsPyKisCRMBXBchaCSDAM5vFXxZ@hNbiFYXtDYDaA/0MwEtD8xS5jhEyHqxCBR7KxoZCnA9ZK8/eHWD2QDogWr7EipB9ASiRAxSAslpJ44VwB8Zw6CcZuJiEMC1m4AdYF4EGJaB8BuiYQUIW4QfvwNM0YF4acCoNmI@mgr8G7iyCh3gFCCtANRZ8Wg109xQy4vloXSI8cG0AoyKlkVGpSCCAADXFslBfBZaDRpDFRpDPMsAdcCkWGPCqkspKOVYqMqBlOcOgXlTAC1uICjxSBXxUBAZ1r0Llq4CTCpRWAaiazTMhQmg1i@GQNgtpgSxqDtLkwA2VphbwB@mgVaiQpQp5alp53gABNy0P5c1nqWVqBajZIoQB3TTAVYOmpAG2WgnCMW0JaFjChluMpzkhdKQD1Ag2dWiDQIw84ENwIS64tWKW008fjgd62/DMDk/Z7mHSAnaBApIRkmawePDMITUBlQyAwR4A6GtQ@1nsKcKVAJ2WD8VRlgec4QV2d2RgyKSBQdnEfuftMGEFLCYJHHGRWwL7GkJ7hCGioyMrw45tEGMK4JiezCATGDcN@wzHeeIuC9m4xIHaDg7rMFx0DcdhGBdkATdNvMqdtF3j9QQHpDlePWB@BvDInm4OQwSoQ@oecVJ4xl3Ib7aIds@xR9RrR8iLhrY9XsH3gfOdI6BH9rkxR33OGPXxeAjDD/gbfPQDZM51ElBImonmyhGCRJiuMzABIGUFbNt0jA7R3i86pM4Cg19EscK0@r0sQnkQGZeybGwDz3YxjTUZDiswYBgdlq0rXeNMQR8@di2OWYhDMJrBmOSDaOsgXCDmhEUI6Z4m0zh5HNSsa48Wi8YZ1X5Y9IGJI8zwXJ9B7fWARxlTfQQiEEM5w4JRcQQthtcg1gQIeVisfda1rbgXQjl3QBqAQoclIYkDaeKZIwPERRuSYI3nCGlkk4RZewZNmaiVk0k@5JhcI5QsXCcU98hFPHhngXGzO@kg1TBv06IWBOONi8KSY@hd7id4Djs50eHnwMA49kViGR0Y8QhRi0huMKoaQH1fhOkQRBzsDcsFOcyVmYkCK7T8vt2DxnZuQtlBRIKkc9gdIgKSIPSayh1ZIJJjAxqdDpnJOuMxA38QPKB57mVKMJbbX5jsDQQOByCLdSaOM2PTMdSEOYJYXsfu9aD1vjHGAwDBRl3WmXWge0IlY@sRujZxos54sZjzt3UD4lgo3e08@zrrG0B2GPl7KM5jk58XYDymIhApdItLBZYOlMIidMYzIguACVP0bFtG/65tuNRYbOc07PqYmWv0qWtAP@vNmdEIpRxopRZJZ13gPH73QviYobC0MJiV3wo@NizoOh1oldDpofqwTrdZD7SSiCyAApve6Rhjz28nNrEz04oITgd7KDiRr@QDk92BsH6fbV5rNRA1bDkRoQAFSUR97MtzOvJaX/UBMcEy5rI75yzD2Y3sIcbZtdzFVxhnAYNX4gocxtQlUIokJjHxkJUgdzQ7A@SFHnIbElygtzmTm8UHv2j2zohJvTBvxEYFtiPISuiFeKyGIcFveBOQPB4irPqCB0Zd8LgDtO6OlkC2QySH3aivrOgyMMW7gI5sy14CFYgZwsUoiyFUF9QYj5Br6MOwMVJ3cRfqCBn2XBvHgQzG0PHYdqBncKYzI5WMqizSunxNJhGOFUnQ5BeHVhgy4jjgezgKQoLxEPQ36mLYU0FE1YFTABPjmgbwPJvnGEGYej3B8vE7J9bPGxOMpZZloJSrOzMOBIoHwzNkNGOm4wAbPMNBgo9BwWAiUzuFMQF0LuSsSA7q99czl7FF70za5vS6OtNBT/kLVzjTHdZDTcYBoQM6USLec@PJKvlTykiQqNhjT6Gk/C5CRIokQ5UneqAcwSCxB4zmaGZ1EuJCFxPTTJx4vZKYBAcm5DIa@6o@9q5j9wX4YaMZnUK/prcq68PwLUlwl9CPMMEARcYA3QE5AzohiOzlcrets0vgHqCWT3coNQqX9FTlXJiXYXXDvHxCIC7R8so8C9fpkEOKjGpYAoxOJadBYoGA70kJSiiCh6L4Yyt6kLTHw0iu4Z4TiyYuWIKLIkl2EQr5MAAkCBkThA@zY3otX1y5dy8QXNZqNWhsIE0B2@wmo@pBMMMjA6eGyDJJI34msmcfedg3EkkoL0a@4tiA2AQttVZnF97AgR5H71cCRAKyCha25ICwfj0/NU8n3esVbaEnRhKx14HQZHY8sSrA4M97Q@02qsYXqAoqRBypio0X0xPoG42XfLFCRT@aY7go/tZ8VCI1nEAM/La6lEQ8qe83b9A7s87QFwm4Czo750ZtQP/UnxEIGVHalwmCTnujp3Ig2B04HPZs@/hRze@LPFBpm1ZlwWNod/Qhea9jdDFI@3j/weH24ddbS2AMzXbluodi5koFHGonU6lvTZScrFXWozDmgB@2boeNCRfjiIIfzCR7GhGVZh0YXKYBOQ8OP7lOEpCEkByUA7jxd02k4XFA6BLauju4NgizfioFWYZJgrhM2mcBzNCBqGO4HuDzbPLmDVbedaTGvj9iNpzoHEDgqexbQToZA68JYEFQu8dHREoLUqhp4czs3BWNGeDzMUrN15EhUTrSZD4@2Ns9rBFYf5JCoiiK64EspTtdGdr8cNI1hGVxgP2Bq8NS8hxxlKcJ16UE7nQWCDyvW7YCPgBAXUe2mTQcBUVzB4D7zvWyka/UCVsAvROE63JlVB7qfCiiETxwiOugyrtsFKWA@WAVei0dscLQxWGrk88bxVw5Omx15nl2o0BpdhXGgUBudCDo1JXQR55Lkb5Y7aN/9PgG4i4JkaAKSAFm7pDJlJc7FFB7kUwWd5Ud0NDsoSG/II4nMjGpKPFgglXuuKR8RuLvTk0vkUnyp5qEuJD79va@9jCI7M/90UwGKQ2oi@PI5PRwQaTjQhux7KHdt9kGpOHSYZAhiE0ri7ndt60bNaSjJxY1hmsqwH9x4kYfw1hjviHFkVJF1VW@OqNb7jlwabWQRSIRhQiUQvHlL/QzHcg1L/fR/ue7MIio@UwmdGfoAhJE0hC50NWJ@JIHkyAj2cdnaQHD9ZUbvT0IkCILHFhon9GFCbfnwUs9iWPKytL4S1H6qn2D4l/Ys2tNC3x40wJHhGT7T5893n@6@2T7sxNPy@cX3nOZcgEIB/m1QRaSB5xu2Fs3eNfEYiG4GPQNB7sXcIEJKCjBtPvEdYBxyxhF5gisaDV8ZSrxVXtgxd3k9cKcY6j0hdXhTegJdj4e1U8IinZ3iMqIw5f3cDzH9jPwvLFbURTo5YNJWwalVfmiYw/1vkLpYGAYDhUVVZf9A5zXcJelAGTcmcFT8MktEB1mNIOoD0c2KC@0SIisgSU4eJq1Gpr9AejCuJJoOEk5bMFUGqULGgLoykpYNmLA9Aa09Z9BPYm8aX9F1Uq8XasZLaeIQbSF7g9x13oGqE4JGK2AFMlrr@zk3sk9NgMujZCuA4kxeYMmOVyGY8GQgSBJs6ao5wfEIW6B86XIK4hGryc4mwtcSslnckW1kFdALQM1DWRWCefcpJHudQaSZ0sAT7J7NG8QaYU9t6NbPXnDdwTIgtz3ERQ123h5cmI1QUA/uUe44QJeY9ZsqM1kld1MsuHHT1ah9S4UD9tu4AFtl5zQNOnJVvCzrn6TnXV16l1dpnijsT/mSGP2ZBsEqTc28OuuEe17mECJBiobC3EVjPxWWTIhNMSkAt6QUgp0KBhpoekpiJcEQi@Kh9BygG9FErD5bAYvB18Qj/ARVLqx3Zt23KUZf5RrcLbUHQMRabK5g1zaxflBD0bHsOUjl4bKRSbNzo04zqPrLp@thET@YmmQHnS1EALNyocz0la4DAyNgFKReg6cA9oVTpsO5rOMqPRDS4MMCSecfAAJwqLVgz7wGUjMC7LNC8JzIp/FIp1a9rmF0NoGK0lt0@OT/fbEwUVDsxstG0TPajwOQKPCRfg6rS62jQ6fZeWJqRSgBOpsZIxsnEoA6YpYgUFF0PnKJOqCLs5YQ7fKSLj8AvAldn8HuFjH4PNF0giVKGhSuyzuOcq29LmiS2@gNd8iW2Hht6NL61TpxwEBFteJaZbEnwEl6cQeUaQXNN@CgQ8CcVcYz7wBlBhamKjX7LFhXdf5uEaYSFZpPTceB4ZvWomL@NraWrwSr8fT4NoC1ya6ttCVAtcWuSRyYTwZXZQiTS4MbVAK9GvGrxoB5GmyiW1gipLDG3Oc0BuVSraZ1huq/9TwmYSqAMpDbAkfACeerNXQmUyK9XNcswH5PVL2HWw7Rx3HHPsk@CoIBPzdp0GWiADqPUrzjlFF3fR2ioxqDiiNBoqYCSd@0sicNE8uTrqpk6t4GlMnq3oN9ENgXl5iJPcdezIGwa2Rq0jA25KNbKVZbdfimfhGIlGShpCRnkx@VEqmdE7rRNyANpU4OYkDSX3qNDoDh@BN01oyGRIK8OiZoGUMh4m4fFGC/NvJZjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7p0kAguFRpnBHgj2jOnQEromDDERdcUiEHS4hR218@N8WDmRCOEs24gZeMM@nzRH/dGIBePcsk3PH1UoFvQ9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs84dxc4pifKwpaVYNw9k3oj29OVT2VQmuTIcBlfiyuSBCMhhXBIVOwnpotdWLcMe@JGZxqXToBi7uB7PJgAswz286ShVZljwegMbBZfvw/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDtyPBDJopSCS6WgHRBOzNM4Iu0p4VmZVRCgrOeYG4@Xxi/lsPcqpSGZTAjs2/ZjiEBSSCFQNtQaBOTUGf@Tph9mvm6sS7hh9KQhoq3aQBH3BvaOtGWs@vIetB4FEkP@jkkOTS6whD4Rw/Yo8zrwjG6yoZAq7S2M4ARAkqDnFgLa2vkByi2O@7K3hSSCgkccKOBXLsDofOcdTVNK3TyvUoQhq0CiD2ASkKt1AIVNwiSVAhM@pW8y6eFAh396cHDXT53QoMtDq84j9Ya2d0JyJW@3nRoWP0024X2ZFr2yAQyBOnfnA4PbdvjWj68rJqZ4UqzOZoMdZrzuT4tc2u6jt22hzQVdFvSefyJ4@pDnU9CBaHbnz4BWf/58VFNrkQiKfrZ6Na8cR5yebacnvvRNUdabw2Wh1zeMMX1vIjjVrBNDtmMH1DAgIm/SQ7qKPAvon/QpXANxfcvof8IN8iBrOzPItBr6OlHLFNE3DSHO4d8zws1c4X@K3WwMJ5K8bjgOMf2QtXI/8zr9Ra8s@R9KiFrGs69c@TNN88t6IhRlPI8Eu6kW4gTBVSgOOGGuuvxfOYV7jUYGMNgBfEQBBNcJYOxfYjiE@gmKInzPW8GCNJjXAwhDo1LbKwDsqZ7Y9oC@tRY4rGF2Br1ExjDFJRchHWF@VPcVeoplu0vTbqce9qg2tPsyWadL2aj6uRwrU3hk@/rLQCxWa8GG5RWRcOc4vEwGkEl3CAFFZPW728UNdyN4dKcukBJqoKrgNYw1TLSybS427yMKy6RocfEk5PpRxntM1A/cHfZ@j2lb1Qxw1X0qgYhcV9Ubc@YBIIdxuLz050BsBOWmi6SEupnYvXsYVfii2HQLhhXo7CC/L0I4a43f3OjYTrBhjfacciTIhuN7JW7AfdaldZvRojsrgsBQS@5YJen6bNL1oCR7Ux2x0PTa7Ir2bNbAySJN3Gs6/vwuKjpOPrMFfytLDW2ffjxp41Mk0MQRjoucJV4LU6D7ZwgH4M8hPtrwYUbcjzTowGfNhyYWF5VBqSmtBYC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULUL43LeVl6BiikCQMxd2ejNDOSV3JvqHueYfE2x1cZV5ObLwf52dQo@y1/baHCMrQAAwKoiWGAYpUdHT/cPTyUoeW6ifguLtRUoDvqnQHIIasKHVAyWvgK@6gbZx9hmiRq5wJ0NVAyWn56aNRVaPSgZkDuyCL6hpMAzySusXTAm5a1KCEXxHwC4baqjkc0CoEljCSUiYBVluL/3OIalY9nBVp8iigJ5E7cqwBtzaQ8sczXsgvjCYmnECXOdVIYFmrrCWJq62qSWo9jjnCFGBQpkg2hBI0Gk94A04PIIms2q3ypH@KinuX0kbqiSFVBu35ralD1NfAGyYUg@Mlrb9nLRkYqN1Pry0DRHjJ/wy4vfwQuQlgE7RpLs11PUH@/0ZE5DnzJjzPy56Q1X9uVXmHr3CHyqWWKHuyLIqZD26gWt0MtbraCToashGZcsCABS4j526n9NkvhxPlBtcFk5JFIsouQ6BqSnF1eEg3ZusaIhuBSGa@Mq0DJBMb02IbSPPa3UkeFAOqt/n4R7LMnghhoU4sLshjCJXXl7JoQKp2J0XRcCDStU5uWdUJXKyOreRT8wtSj0@HNlD3THdBtIWqIA4@rrcLOHbV7dFsSgVY3/HVz8qB5c1/kBVlRVw7pQVPoS3Je3CuykG3b6E2sPi0yoptJr@@IKZVLFLnXbpurogIRcPtX8FwSDZgUtmdNzslqsDcbZ1xgPALGxZWUedGvbzNiC3SH0cGDVP7zv36jC/S/WTsDGChwgjF0tGDoxpqSeisry0@KL3RbXrF8HnwyNHUiDLnuAtnRHSiSPgwdy0HTWrskwfA/wpUDv8ahbeINhMNbmhnHnC/8Bc/lmSxbO7OAZXZWxb227YpnRas8oL91iQhcCDINSkSsi1eCMeUrLRFNGtnY3UgFe6MYNWZe74OJN@F3kE/vrERzjL/b@qYfM5PX26oBGqLeNo1bqtzRTyddWxqf9kM5tbAk7rz0tNQrgTjgr/q20Lm8@LyAjtmHcTZ4roo2H9qUc3rc1Spca@KOpTYp213@Rh1hdEsOzpDfV0Ux/UNNoWM11cwh3d6zJfrQoaH4mx4U3FIqRYhmXiPzUG/PUAYZfHgrCzcQAMepdVKpTHbFCvJ4vDo9KoyUvlxennoqdzg9lk0FKHzbqsQny6jA/kbWO2oVhitzpA8lrRtxrmTmy/Yf3IgaLl1SGuMMF27OltbcnPo4IHUmQ92Zu25p4nM8gtWCVRPP/rDxzOzYIA6MmVqUVS0YOiIDBrHMYAfcPCPcNUy3yC4HcxkZu6AW4iAuha7lLMDueLgzdEWbeg@Gxndk4r7XSCOR7VWU6tjn@FspPgxANeX35SPam6VYvQdzkoadoQ7j@MrhYGEOEOcY72io56Zr0G05YU@XIup1hkv9F7tAMLsXna27q1m75tB22RHdbyNQ3wEq8PvyBh2lpalbEs15R9238KBgK8O8QvVh3x4WSn1Fh9vKWp84PeT7/vN9OVzIoVT1Dg4ViD@2pfrPlXz9VHFO76ogOuDl4DbWiPOWIXYZm/KXWFaXDhQDXJ9bXrK9TIlSygqf0VuRMa6snOuz4Pl3GDpWkTYYOsYzEqdBusME5RI4PIeL2H@X3HK359Z9P6Z0A2zxrkJEKvd0aMBgRfcbVcq0jPqBKdRM5v1ZVG84MSbGUkXjoP2FgceNb1Ey3h@pjF@MdX9CHtcA8ARKGOuNrxm@F9Y4TuPbrcxEH5od425RZpGpjUH6HqPq/Awcz9BxM0XfmowXanVBO7MObyfZYBx0abu7gB2GfCgfKt0hKS3I565Bv1s1Jq7h4T6wWi6TyfgCTGRhZeHlNk0qG6b9wuT3hYzJZ57zPC4upjkR5/I8iCzRnYYrWZC2SrGnyOWyYpmW4c3w/p7ctG3bww@pKWCqXRNFMZAsaUftbTV2Q9zxz4qw@dSFixMe7d6qSQs@2vi6JdAHlebbKj268vNetSnh2uYI150WX2@fvomsI92VC57Txjkhvsd2uFqW9GdDVLkkF2/tdVxCtdvGUOePaSF3G7yynL0V3iLT8NdkcQ2Xr9zOV9xj15jSeAbEMrugpQyMkUGvt0j5ehdNCviPlZGmNv5WBU8No6NMd43OqghjE/iChfeFpeKIsOTZFuhXHm7nQz1liBtGfd9VHDhY3FtK5P2R3je4LYvbOOV8wgI3zXC1bu5cPnVR4RtlOpBsbrxgdZOATnVqzNzguRTgk1kH6nUyunu67Vrn7@Ac6Hv09lU7VW8OsdbAHlgDY8C3h4dvqzoHtEeP2x65DXXAuj/AHWvj8cJO9ig9h/Zw@D70RNbIGaVt95bitItnXPGA1gfBneltCPAfd07e6R7nHehY2WsGxgTGJdf27LEh0duqqEOc6OH3VTw0WIv@u84g3arnA0WC598V/p26ZV@3vfGYHq3xcOLSjZJKdDT5Lrmpx3eg0N5H2@nLb@xRW/Y9ZX97Ci2BL2cxbdPrDPBsOG/ZRt9udwbmXUi3Dd2zzFMlmPLhr@@luyJlTCY9RG95aAJ5nZmM7aUWDT/Cx/6qSvdnj/iwFjpukVeWzdDR6WtprJ92XD4bii5WwQnhSG/kZ7QrdMq98npienOgkS1L4fQuX5ZAxyrc/U0SKyUrOgoxZ8P@5omVrZSEdBTIJSMDAo@6KtvF7WyRLpbN8tsqhKKlJIwi208@hNz@Fh@aHTQj87bgv9C@FvYmLR3krMGk795kmHy6vgsiGt5WT1vQluXIlDWMWbrlP1aRWRsqeJYRni2QuSbGrWsq@VsXVSieOpR024RHCx5QdZOVc2hDc@zyO5N6K5fi/C1LoItfXy/ktJktV6b9iukaPb4Egq67RMSR7eCGY5BBpA6upOMMOjJzLnhxxmXZfWDq0pDNIwdxV4ktS3cDLa/@cMyUPntq9HXcUv3Y9HBP5pJWQU122S6iO2F/baK75tcmULJVjQ0NM/BlSCd6gh/flsB7ovfNzqOFigiR9Ansb@jkj4Xmj1436@J8YLq4oyl03DIxhU2ON2JsdS3QG5bEvD5vH9qkmHcgftpxaexlc@v2eIaHwmbkum1a3fRoltV/rlIdV@31uhWJ88loPHH9x3IcaM9UdBZ6dEr@7rkJwKXXwFrZQB96y2eqI1OuIIX5g@LcuUoa/9wc2n32eSnDQGgDIQyF8yUN5wEMz89wQ45jLWmJlPd7LnviRIfk8IK9hro1skwyLdO7fTbH83BzTvDEwvCRAw8iKI/xLt//UAjS8XKKPL5b1p@fQL5jfIeWd2RPnI6BztCsSFQt8HM1doJNxnhww0azKOdRLa1jD6F7gWO4tMt0bGviSc7EunVUKNw6KlTYtFSINAOW@Nruk@fJaGugTdl3SaEGKH8Tdzibu1ZuGLjWyEwLBLHVfHQxdqBLPOTmkA5pR/AdabbRZlOH2PVDe5m@82wGA8h7K0zA/Cejh0YHlw3vzPup/cS2bBiNxsAoR4cGP9q/sNFjeUJM9hgPrwN9undmc0RgVwxCXNrQx0Yb6nc4d73PWMQBP9Q9fcVQRHODpP@FrjvbijlsG84XNOkXca9SaRcRemRMSbdY3WB4H5S8ToeLxDgft9BHFlZs3LFtW/xO3DYDD/XJ7VwFhgK6vf9CuYz77RfmBZbqZ4tFPTjju0SMLrc9saqsjtG2h/x@y54ky@R7AnTHNFzlMZoyIL9Cjkkgfbm38pDirTxkrhqBJHumu7RIv1zVmINUpx@wBWigOx0bV8J8xy27cyL2B@5g0@EWfr5xoA2EnwLH0jsT37jiXWgNR@0R3VYqDJHaPDTaePinTUY7PH16szL5zJBvsSCyoys85x@wK@zUBZZ4BtpI8u5ha0GPWqSqOaYbceqVy@W0WUeyTKPzRsdZM5voNZ@bXgiHMitPyblirjrSjWgWWdHpQPvSnrS4dQ0EmqEheQMHdH7Fu216O7CmsmQ9ZDIycJF5cRVmpehquwMqrL18PT1kro4h@Sb9gJeE5v24fChtr5Q8ETz8Hzz4qgKDcKuQCyyMAOu6ewUfkJ84lv94nxb4zHa9njk9ALzxFMAqdoLFykMSePCega6NVYWA2rMmQz770I/suxp1SR2TyGqtJA2JXXuGZFhnEtl7m94skc3PdinbaO3UM7qSb@4AVxqkx8ExrzCa/1yygBrljbjZU1U4YaeFnL/9cxlxzwPOAPKW7Uljl57K2H22//jgWB676tLxaXuApyNuyHEL9hO0UiYyJfWF7kTWO/l2tK7pesqDI1XaebwvY4QV9OYrGhI8cGVu4bFy3tM3J6or@kotCEMNb7mA@Oj4yePU/CQmS@wMHHtkJKPBO0dHaTxp8tWjpcHR1HvQO3r2dGXy/V1VTS5pvs8tWh1cxT2X5LQK0rEB2ig0xkfc/MqdwlXHHhvd49nY@BQGT@Tg7ntmX1hZyKf6mdnHXsjKKwlFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcq24YTPVfV5ao6RW3boofDHyu0oKDlkFSe7XHq4bcX/uhTDMv5OhA9LpGZutlbPlKBn9AfoUnT374uYqqqr6Hyk96BeWX5lZS1GWLY@PLTP3mMp2fCVFyn0kjxoVZJ55z7yojQC1q3gDafnfU9wtldug7kNQOhdWNrhzw1rplsSrWXdJl5UIDVuars1yufGeyxIhTt8ztDA89I1vnBLPUt0yJm8I@NjJ5JkZ@fB/l0JDn1a3h7r46fP2TPdRVsjt0eMYmy8B8ZzyegLCeet0NDdyuXUrgOgtFvh9cfL@3OFHelO17Zm07sX4eioKQ7tZEM4hIVvFMkYmlNz2VjV4fNaz5ZvM7orb36Iw54tyMFRGzQ@oHff/heqmsmQhSF8qhn@ekfNBB2cJdClz9BsXTToeD9kDR2UW2TwSC7VRh8bU9yOwmeDlyn1S8e3wi1jXzG5eji5Lax0S1julvxuhKEny8oZ9RaA@VvCWF4Ogx/bw/OBLe/ojuEu2X@8FKHbClK@pSDlCHd@U8rgJCgtLPru1SI@Hl3wH0tb67HhObnxwG6buaVl2O6hLUn2BG2i3wz3t1PoDm1v6dv@kQ/@vjy/84mxNKMn@pvlAcRpTpcGARM0BhM6EnEzeHGBtA0yr2H1TW5GkT2wvV16W4rkMxt3rC/N8qE5fjgZr0YUWCJa77/OxRcivgBV2T532QM8ETeXzpeo/Lgtbrn/KlGWhfOBaET00fF20KgOjhQtkuMci8@eLXjjmVHv4Cji5xjT6SpdV5quUh2XhsxzfXqcm2fBT/kdTqyoIWg37Zvy4Kdi@VlEVw6sdScSViqVTC5@YyJ6sBLNpSbW0VzgOh2ihLiXl2zNP7gIAWJwFNI/qolWxUCRMvCspUAgvNo6ZFOrqfky28IPO1RATEpSjuhFtpuCvBps/cI/hVipqFdsrcbEisj8c6ChKVZuThTgoiFEKBOTTlW27kHIenCGkZFlfHbJSPUCWU/NZ@BNVqKnuav@KU9Aaf3i2f6z3aPj7ePnR41M88o/BRoUwrIgt@Cs@UfZrghl98kGLJ0bF6bTx0PIjqz2o8rmBuViULJrRastFG1eKHEL06xfWJai0EFYRboC/CSR50ahIJ@hF4cdlJjqxz8DXeFnUuloLVQRBy1SnlBnFZZZlvFYB/a0bvnh179AQqH4hZoKfqMGM/btwULn7Nt218/RNdjdV5Dj3vb@4@eHuyxAcN5ozs2uN6iV89xcMD@cD/XUM2lnUI3F/SRxqKtaLb4XB8LE5Tir0NFlMtUL7RyiBdTBQ89@6g2WWCf4QMF4WCnKf/2GchWXcZNrEuLGA6TikC00eWooa2tr7BgaCXt4uP/p7iFD/HcfkjeSCEGwYzw3@ac/7nJj94H5kuDrPM6ImAqZiRCiZ6eDA8XzM89Ic@q649Xf6CHj8nSyOLRqH36WQxDoowfQbs/J8tg1q1RJMhTDvynkGw0LMqImFBjIxvlUNADmuOzMdE0814w49NAe12Jjxy0YZINOZtv4ASL8zJFOX14A1CeWx23e@BYyYtDS5JDlpNk6Icu/0yBGIsY316Cxtw0YZphrgZJqeBX2BbREnLOs8HPvklSP30gSgK6QSxp4o2Ek4g0DXq5y4ijvfuWfKf0qA7cH7u/47mnmAbz9kv/WA/cvc/dLBRvaTYNfc1yiCKGRPr8EHJGQ/kj7yHeXLG5rYE44tEsW8FVmjqCazojqGJ3nwO8SsOM5nETjU6g0aG5QY76NAZ6f4TQTaCWwoijYpFD0kWmHtzHl262uWQss5As5VQEkpbMAIJn37uM5Ug4wmaxANxHOzHHtFYyrm5ubTET9x6gVqrxmlXXrZVZ8FSK6DnGF8wEi12CQBpLMU0BY3U8Gg09KTWJS5F5xNY6Mq2vDqEThOHrhu@UTQmQJIBankYH2oqf4iS7PmQVWL9v4UavIpx/WfUCSCmMSuZKi4J/Of2p70Hygk84/7sJP5@N2Qz4Cojk5l3@gjoxNYnuUb/as@aHS4BsTfl@TkQdwUNnM9cE0WrfiCwRxhCAq4rLm23jJTrwTq6nwtsmgmf5wSWO2wP2LSn9Fm@Xl3r5pajBx3VAgEovdP7JsVPT2oDAsoSlaVlELyXmRcrmlRfJL5GcDxUFDJ5eQHbApYBkdw/zCHrvbO7v7Xz14dnTDnB7FjF@PBny/vpk6keR0oxk64tFiLVbJgz3l6MmDvaAi5kgXItwYGL9fEvW2ksznbxDk/DzA9aItw/B66VZj/IKfGL6Ob1a7DTVKdAMPNfMB@dKeXGmPTtZcz1wrLaNWPn8bSnN4SgT0Dj8WeQPVRPLiqtHcrJ9YsfjNlrCkI7yMyRvYCcB14m6sK9jYbxYOCxZ@OvIYvzHlRvtidnlfFNezaNUJT2V79uncnpXvEQmIlDfIBlikICtB1JW974DL6HOraxr/tCW3/xS1bhNBuJC5jeIRUMfBVzKRi8xtRvrmEge6OxiabSGwKsTNJgbW3UKLidwiUCIp@F8e4Bkn/O9mTitTmTbgJJLI7QhWmt1mgTGAlxSgQ6N092wCqtwze8wtUdNC60MjcB3awH5BfyQNzWBfnYwgXo8ehwZNegPnliAxUDIeosplKeASvgHGaQpNXEJ@DTTD6BdcHnXziWlSHhjTrtkH3p5IpoGjfaSqTRYaacRCk1FGKy5Snc1r4dau@DEedo2S/YMsdU7nCOgNXQYN0Jgm4ufxZKUJ@aN//PzFWTwpLmtLZDHUN6HZvW46NES/qN7OSXTP752BXc5l3KJcvsklwO86YG7bKvgMTrksD1yBPmtWQ8n9yHMegxPEiERvpI9ZYmJxu2Ayo9fEScJKk8Ekqc5NC1oslSKFCh4UIDNK2SMXH78TujVjCaUGjQB9XauLjzfmmDVUWW6CmzJJsnX8PNUOSFxoEC8pgA4MSSoEtoZNCNQMwIh3Epk3cEiD4RAXHmRdbUkwfa2H5gZtpAmVmtXvscjnxhYlR7FcrvgVusgVywxa3012KCsA9gafC@R6oK5vMgRoBuqvLMTmjPwmx4tRvjGOyCPf1gigE4uYAw1MkDCANTfW2Rk4@EvsWtBXQD6oVJ4f77VKSUVkoc2SvmN2ce6aW7QOVTz/GyTQTZWFqPEq1@g@xmRoHa7FjaKgkbI96jDiNZYai5Lh@teA521TVW9t9X5CvxYgZg4HAP9sVysAh2YQg10ES8KWM/uf/Qy/Nywm1lX1tOWcpeL5TBVuajXP8uyj9RNJWm9kavfXddCivNfTE9DJlY3cwzNj0Gvv95UTUWRZllOUjfjexjNTK7x8Pb3KqqXXp2O10JBfT5tiqZY@bbJnzz5723qbFKdns9fiSYIsVLGdg0tRzaGaH6uU2cVWIRs7LeOHJeEvj2rNG9LUT9kbuE57DP/J/aYbcevobvcwrhgXWezkBL8jLBZFRWnEm/BPQF7BxRX/Rl2uy1vNt2@TDV33pjNmmubY7XbhZw9AgtSSRxjtHnB6iq@wk@i8wWjaW5hH0POsruExP/l@C9/JzOB02@j3J7v6zJzseU8@fxFcz/F6c7h0QqKZSiUkqXHdu9LS8zGmZbQ//cnaVfriWWvzT785Uow1fBzg4ztXT9B9pOY/Wlv76MGDXC6taRp3P/v82de3t7dzD9P5Z438Vk7KrG3@yR@vrWnapqasNV1XbcYbp6efiVomJ8p/@qN469mzr7luPft/fONtXcVbEW5nrAh8Aq4sU8GJ9xL8VJSxGOmVd1@xNzFo5WpsRn@tWBiwxtT6VvG/fe/gdcyL1TXlhQNPL/Y6VijFuBMc8JYN3s5i9dgmRitcxWZKrVYDZ/G//XtIX/8qwMGQ2Sbc6vkAVmEWq0s1SnIZqxfAoWoa5Pt/feMbEQw5m6iRGBdc91kDLjFX1MStJlwbdG0KaAtOyihKEM/yBp5hM7V0T72HLya8wMMy0Ha24Z3E8EOt7OA@Y4eNVCrVlFsSXPJLal@qqp2o6vgesAPpo41aTdpg3NpdNpu/h4Z5kzSl1bdhxDTuvfjHuGLLPKsfCORQiBXW7r96WK9DSbL17EY9Rde8/yisWBJt@77I0uxVHBSPRvPVY95jWF3MlDQxnU7zbjRFAknTefuhD7rH@BX6MHRf91tIAlF839iHx4vt4vVn/@ufff/Pvkd/36fff0ITeVbX7CkbEOkMOkIdrvuVSqdeF@uOeHGC73VoPZlKqVJSWlcniQ3gO81DpmY@vozns3FgMSr9sZMkpYaLsq372eN7PTb3rnOfetTPD@CRyYP5pSDHAtXIHVLtRjwYUP3NhFLjrN6UUAyqSQ21kG9KPFWAZb3MGvehmkStWBabdS2vHUDVqSKvuMG6y@wY6IOFgI4@vvV52ephyPytHvWK1YNk9XmcD40XoFsXYo2G0jRoGAj82P21ylqpUqhoSiv0vHmx6k0vwzCeubGzWHhx6sTmBI2FTfO6X1AV4QsLWjD7kHhCTHqfGe4PugD6Flxr8Ef/cIWveF8jH9@boty81lhF3dCySv6jwq72gfkLMDywTrvdftNpw/iv6229o6uePtGn@kz32pP2tO11Jmjf5v3LJMTeNtbYIWdDTZYKrpPUnddzWW75TnLY@JMkexoTYv8IV13VVLYBw1IGbiCLkRNUZfxTVYHFLuBqvt1ovN2AHlpPbRJ7bNYlH0t4yK37zZR0ddUAd7Xq/2/WQ2eVLu6CwjWvUqnNl3WQOF7WGykA@dIHKXOYcqve3KSAMC8/Mz94swkii5TabGzW7B36QRK4pCYA3FxA8v79lAyu@5Cyvt5k8ZwdL9j3WTKVWpekNRwRG/5YAWma9VRQKMQhASLGJvS7q82r@lVj8@pqcxP@N@l@5T/B92rzxj895teKOPPwJmtktVITucRJQ6mfKCd@n2/Cu6zU0UdWTsBRhyfEA9FAiG2wjRjaLsvGNoTYq3df/s/4O3n35e@hwMTgz6gIsQts4MoGqltlrnXBjVlPLPaEXxa48Re8og96PKmjp8VvFq7IKMormVX4pHdCLRWSMo5FLbvXwuPQMnsFURkyaCZqpYLYSqkzjcU2xUKRWPTP37ji8fg/eaWVi3E@O4FneF@5rvskgtkcN4hc1TKqpF7WuZlq/uGAn192/ZOfX3UJscsyMypAk47LODWEGFRBTJKAXdc3R7jHE5cHJNTEzmqfSc@3JZw60D1a/Olwtbi2v1srl@t8ZWP9GbWZjYcbcFfhf3cNSiHE2q/x7/Eb/GPHHfw7fI1/7PgN/h16@MeetPHv@DX@bbfx73iEfw9e498TD/@e9/Hv5OeyWbUqrl8QAVJqWb1an4pEiGpsq37yc7xqevGffveb34zXanEpTl8syKm2w9RkFUjouvHq/bgQq7F1dV3NDDOdjNpW2@AwWcZhmUFmoHZBOmipLGOwzCwzY5mRrXbBZcBfBlxmpscyfZaxMhZEhFBwea2Mh64ePPrw1wNADvyZuO@orWY6DDIaohhOnzpD8OC6bJ0IDRZn4isDdCRZlTNywWziByIa4qtXJ8pGUyuXmIztQm41Xp3Em2hKWCvnWHtmrJ28YjEXlKxqTDk5Ufh0EZSVyHF11WrtPn3YainIM0@e2Afz/4ODUfT11v/Rgf3kwB7Z8H9wcPCEMaOeup8CrnL/fg24jP/YitWrWycVYlIBo4opm1sn9ayE7kIKWJCGfqkPvOYQ4VlfOxHi5wmUj89RRK6@OK@eVcl9HryCo1WdRwiicYf/hOsc@HEgPJ/DdXaODnpD5/mLk9DFHcqLc/B6wUA3CP9BCYm@/gP8m//v@n/ynCVZotFMJi6uNhN0JfEvmby4urjy7/VkIuG/JDbhDz3gHZNcXNXRSZEuwNVIJJvJqyvuB/dEcpMDrEM2m3VKO48HnDsWZknZ8lviH/YJWfvXSbzK9PlGj5OTaSaTrLYDC@i4bKlf0mp6skpfuVpvN9Tmn/yIrNxvJSlSPletqhuMv2g5rVrNBW/FUrVaCl7WE4nyzaue2VILIBrncslktQovWwHYDLyGYEsANnjJA1TD1Ts@F7zYPyD778Al8jH88AJnC4kMfT0CP0QUFyvivXsJ/wPHW9vJe/e0cubyMvQZj8FLXfBqtbqm02qhf/byUmyJtO@inIf3TOnyUs2UU2o8aTuJp/gFK8gqIansI61OuZaB@Wq5YvIfRloGYPnNzUKuXi/kwF0o4QrwzYuowcT1eOwiGK@LSc4a4@uKWOXKF/RuFy92cRWjame5fDIBzDUJMt9VDP@4t1ouc/8kyxUSpVTZ/6utgQ4Jcgj/wxmLbCq3Udy4DxIa/k2XXsiTqxdGTb2qXRgVnPm9qnb874fiuWvj3r1sGchaylRPhFbr4fbxdqtVE0URZRm4oSdxdwE/WzZ24g2q8ny52cASNk/i8Ur1PjUPtZRn0A78eFIchglWKhMhBLOHRhWg9ILqzwetCRo98SaU/Vki8ATJG7PGXxcu1mVt1seL9XEOj5lsSBcbMh5O904njGTzyw8NXyktXqGPEV5C7Nnj7Z3d47S2KbGYtre9k9aOnj@Iqfian79TcBbfD3e3Hx48hwTPHu9uH@1@vP/p7vNn4O@y8/kV8Hn/Pn9GXUvez9kL4QvnjW4YujExjNb5ZHL@mn1hmi0T6m84gULYfYe5RgtwH@vzclTh1zFd/YsvdGdMF3v3w2@/@@F/9@63v/vut7/97re//9Mvv/9t@P0Yft/lz@/@u3Ie7z/98l/8zrvf@m3w/E/w@0P4/eSnX/76N/iP3v8Ifv8l4vdH/i8Sj/8EgPVLP/3yez/66Ze//AP4/Sv/94Obv1/5yfLf97@1@ofpvvc7t8f57r@H3@9yWEHc7/4W98Pnjfi/xeP98g/e/dp/4P9/4v@h87ff/dof4c1/@ec/@JP/8u6b/1HTSn/yb99963vvvvXNd9/6zrtv/VPt3a//WzUTvf3Ou@///l/@we/@5R/8j/T/Y7r/7vv8v/vBP//z/@XP/7c//wP/9xP4/Qdw/eTP/yP0jb/5/R/i//d@/2/@8If4/z/967/5/V/9m1/6N@T4De74v//Vv@P3v/qV//zXv/mdv/zJN/76V3/y17/x@3/5v//y//nr//mv/vvf@6t/9k30/I2f/OUf/tJffPPbf/Gtf/kX3/xyxf3bt96/fA//L/8RfN4fz/eB8z7l@lCfL/9O@Px9qDHPBdoJtO5ffPfrvwAN/NcYe/ftH@MhBfit@P@xplKcH/O3/w84tJtlxpAMuOD3q@@@/V0k0f8AJIL/kF7fCV8WQvjLd@YvQNbfXJLoF3/65b/8Eb3FjEqdFhNwuC5ppdQGqDQb5bI/ZPvrDJDkFxahhQD8nL6DHGoh7DvI29798BvvfvRP3/3wN9798JdwwJRy5fR2WlLvnDCT8u8RDyMW3iceRvwM80/RVJCU@gze2Gd@4GeffSa0LhU8DXP/Enw/Iy9@MR6Ep2X8oCAM/fH4DLtkUbfvzPjOdd83zJmwwFxTJGhsBFJQPsumKR@hKeMLDugPkaYb5JzinXwxeCrgbf4/d04FlsI4/MKvdgVOcvjp/Cy4U8hDNqlpuMxBYhnjotAG96FlS8o3V2ZYguk0NQV9FxyQQwqCHqRYrVZLYcIaxwdeOWr1EiNUUqkalBtT8zTpVglBTB8QFEhZSx2y1kZtyhOmEF49IEdKQK9DUdXEVKn2EDKsTR8yhIXACeyrV7V6qTatI7i3nB6paeoB4YTAaqlp/S281wgmpBNiD98CKqVaKlUvYYZYSF496RavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCJu8@37jP2kaiWxBaXDpFgPDbeU/PYGBGiQ/hJasMvDv0HTvptEMHXKCs/F8bDt0gQ3eKyKUYAuJIkyzKDHy58brH7EDzloFKULTxSHEKKWgS1gNCD4bRPSkhR/aboBfKP1TY@@EJgWJj19XUhVhez4oFMpFMU5pxWaCs@7k5DxaPCxEJZRG@DziUEuED6KuW/HscVnzjjgNlHKf67f3@DfQTFpOfcT2BSKmvn7BiHsplKiRrAr9sp4SVoIAK0UwJ0KcjTGik5KSGdZkyuxTCMHRwc@EiQx8uakIJmrmVVfMd1jslkEoMUspyW02n/KdOTPGTfIVOo/5TXkbj0BVimabkqKEpVhl4sqtWooACj59u3b6FWaLtPZR90U@bv/NFyJQoED24MYDicBedXtFxZ4Ho5Uws5xhI0@QlXkiUFlmAbSYFvEudIBFcirpVKcYoH1JcTG8FGsIJKzQEnPmN1RDS4uLJYyieDwJ0DtnPw5Mnu0@Nxs8kEg75oa7TGjt0xXDeBYdtPH/IDAlq5kIw1Ggj6uKIhgxF2Kxlif/sPD/ePKowX2q@CBCFWpQU/v5hlVYiNxy82Y/5GGBG/1mSLR3ivzMuW0MpZSBqrC7GOgRoFruRWaQtEVXji9h/YU1D506KYVguoxiVpupcJX7cnDG0JcsMD0Kfw2IC8uUkUEOoXEk3HoxNqqyDU6/4WMqYK9aPdY0hwfMBULSML9c/YVMYMpSuhPqwNDavvDdZxL5Z4khEjZVpvZNL4p2WzcFdzhbSaLzbX1oYXEuZ5QtV2gZvqruD1QsJifAUuJnxFYF8BL7ggD9wpx/xtivsHVX@vGFrtSfANY6Kah26WFE6gojk4YRy9qmNo3qDVR35CbO3zzz1Wr4MuLe3vCTFgFwMW7JeSzK48kKmeuxPHoNA@Y13zUxO/wyV3TXc81GfQd4Acsaurqx5A2t9jWl2jV56ii/erDvm0wX011YWYVanU3qq5opDTKpW3WU0TwEPYUHBD1hq0AFrh3lD4X9WFTLLZkgKsShVFeGSzWQHnhIWKITDauvA2U6tJvA1mcyrtXMCpAUWf1rTw8uNOP5rHzWZ4XAyBANb3HJYJwoo8zH8rCPQWW8O9WvQZ0arfNzP37mVxuiKby4TzEv//teSiNZbNcT2bUTeVMTh1cOY2FR2cbXDmN5U2OE1wljcVE5yTelbNbCqTusCETW6xj6FBgJroGVM0EMr9xLprDHsyHnKpiZSBJm76FnDrfro6nhay9W4NT43jyY5E8kLo187pLKFg1PoyGh9wLH0odGtdu0OfAxa6ctvuzmTXmw3xXMjQdmpxkPTiQYCJH23GM5M1A0QNnMnaymZzlQZrymN7vCVo@WKqoWZgjMCfWkpr6TVjq1isdOXO0NCdrXwlX0p38ciJv8K0lc9U@vJnTx4/8rzxoUHnULZyZUiAlnvQxsZWqZLPNxsNUUw1KJsmfqWUcyBpbQ16raF3JXj2bMtzJa3UhMRd06nV4vGtrKpJaiWbKQlXIYUEoC0WsC5gyhQWLI30vfC7eMWyLWAnlbSeNi@ICJVer3e1cZGavwj6hcTfgDxXkp5uX4SvVSkSr8ImacmcB4KP3gPCX/graxVRy5fEaqM6fy8WxGrzSrg/MrqmjqdPTjIXN1MVgO1yqDHI6IQJVxXHtr1K2@jZjjGPmFULQUSO0M0IOfEqzO4kgzle3MyugJGAhpxy0Ji5CcU67bhsqOVccxcYRqO5GRhXxEYce/lS1@t1qLCLXFHL5XN5LVso5IsaDAzlXCFfgr6RKWTymgYAcuVSuXjFEjB66bpUr2W1rKBpkpaVsqqkZvH/DoeG/@8fX4N/De@QKqsJx2ih4CmMODBKWuwxnnT2bHZs47cu@uyB0VkRY2eg097UHcd23b9HnAe6dcqDHprcLGAY9EjHD/64I9MbrIjxfDxC4waG848GYXfUBgSJTVCEB3Bzhra9LEKRPX@2opRPQkO8QAxuiReiH@5//Og48jze3d55JBTYg4OnD6898n6kPHu8u3ccvhZ5aJA0H4L4@u7jx9df/Ufu4Plhb2I7@BP2Dp7n5rfQC48@Cjm4FiOF3gTEv@EryWQ4/77G8sXAoQq4Yf4e6JX3fGe@MHdm0PmCn@s03XADNz/iWxGOg8OeOkMO1jZYh9uwQEWX7Ev5YrBaLAvCmFn2OStmWNceDnX8enFvDTwHOh5cM1AWHNLHtzHrc9sZds/NrrEmPMEzcmUVvxSLSAiPAMho0iFjLiAHoLXCLn5XGBd82sOJwSb4Te8VnvBAL3Q6Zn8Ag9i5HUQQ2rrO4PehF6Q3opd3u4fH8yC/GyHDm9GFmCCKj3RPn96Plar1TKVy7576zBHLW1nR7Rv13Sk0V/Ycuo/uzNKlvOjJ4h6TW7G@2ai6zTFUWUE9reTscV2vgxTfAJm3U4WBcSuXrwBt66VM/q9@88d/@8e/ykplrV9TN07iJ5mdDAyhDpp/RJEcRUJGUp8vGcqkJGjlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU06FfFMojYGbWkFkr5spou5cpZaIJlCM2Xi75cqQSCpLJRAbBWBz9mukl6hjwAhYKv@bE3CT3JYnr4PmGiAWlEAVU6j84Fb5g1GKyYmmHZIgOIOuuw2N7eTmZvTxQf4AvuddjJiGIXX/KlTKb4QBQNCtkpoZQi2jxNCc1CiR5/yWQe7IjihANAi8qiOMCX3QJOSomiiS8723t7mE8PXzRMD9FOeQh/GQYvRYhm4QvIuwTgdQgNom3zfHKE6C6@YJYYssdDdiBMFD8O0MGQQx6NA3gUlHR7WxT3@cv2NobsULHzHNFP8GWbLlF04AV6gyj2wdF3oB@KYhuc2CdEsQOuzkwHP/xwLBrdtTxdFGecPEggUZxSbL1zKoqtwB@z@dTHJo/UrdCLykt9n17K@CeKWoA0RsuGL1lRzIUvOSjbo0ef6gOva/T5NXP4swMlffQoq5vTye5e@@OP2/1@25lt7358iEE7O49AXphNnHa/7Sdst@CyIdXOI00/Hc2uX1Dq/Varog@XBn3SauV061pQa9YyEENI9Row868@ZjRq7UDQzqPWfX3Z@isBbCE7GMGzjdeDETwf6G0eFFwURM9puy1Wsfmj@E2fc4eeSF9WT4/0jmNX8X1aW2MsnoinZ41CplmlADYCQTtTvaLvuCfwruMkSvJi1pjWMs3atFbU@N6dXkI8mWp5U0yvjbbUcr6ypm@pWi41raBVArsXZ3FJ3WIJ9d7GG5Z4mtzSQNIWT7a2JLGhNrc0tVQpFF9uTEQxWcH7VrZYgYiZeIYxvCUbxeZWMR9JUiymdEWrFIvJ6hXQw4PxvY2TG61E4tzQT5NJRBdVbSgC/4r8jMppVnuJaXpa43ixWbI6ralVbmeSZW7A6qJR40nHsx0OsQ/gpluZCn2nXlTLJRHyV5REMokqMOm4ijDfHfjia8enx8efCcgQ6/4UwDP@Deaq//rxox15/yB4Q2PE8h6qObYj7yC7WgjhtnIDr2MQ9OVHMKCCzhP44dkvxx7Ku9OOMUZdKQgITEzKvmFA@fjRApyjgX3Oc8aj81WyLmV1DIa2ms0u02t1cOldliCsmJ48p6G8Va/XWrURnS6HIgapPmFkyHgOZt/luIcH@in5BZ6H8gNatcxVtV2bxqYAp1VjkvpqZHdfaalOtYsmmh/UHmDiague7apRMxzHdsSYWO1tWTXGJpar94xnhoOmKvYP1kGwwENSiR4zkuvsZBdj76A6cCXVHWbNMXs6GSVARG8nF70ir0iaxNeCIl/QqT3c03BV7dVY4mWy@hpenXWW6MoPklu5ajfxgLWS4JN51XvVYxor5Kr07dQEQoJORLTBMuvJWv0TkIU44NNKBRDx6/gUYGJOANbsUoCeHJtX1U5tyBISm7IkkSdX7dcamPoSb5uSKDYlqXHZFOqS9EKoQz@tzmJ6zZ20ya4/y7RVLVOoTsFPLeaqA6hY/eW06tTGE8eoDuHVnw/jhxP1KpATqAZg3lwm3v3CN5KbUr7G/aoE6nII4kdLbtWmVQsthUGTqGVrEJBq5DJp0JDhVkzDMK8V0mohnU3n0lIRfWGMT@fT4AmaDggYiWFCZExMZ6YZWU2rhppOZF6Z3VfJ9GkCJBgiGUumPXvXmowY@EAlYaukV3jqLJnSNoYMasFm@qZEzRQ4RRULBjQfsLGZHiCoQ0MfUopkUmLZjcRwPYFx1o8n491Gs1LZnY6/BkEJ6fVWIVXMpN4kk9XEWrLmGq@FelWoI1ehUo/XoM36U4XMnYwaUMfgUotapdFoYxGLmXQ2k4XSma3L/qZYF5vpzFpBhSq6YiQeMc4xopNnKOTM/cYtlMCHBlSdWtaqgkxTWdmSJpWV/EY@w2fTeEph7LM1pCRLnIjBQdxEPF7U4vFkvIoT@WuiP3MLvIz4WByYavyeuiWC/CVWxLKGEeYskc5aZgLsQAK7EnB2geXKQuxCuLq42gT1WKHtjiBDsjVySXL9vhCrMAZi4Ilv@kdZY@xDd1GmNusv@fMEN3sDXIFMeoI0SrubDBNVMvYpHivfYnFATHdGDU3LNhtaEQYyYI5BVFDMq7h2EcNd5XIdKOxeAH6bqTqeyPqEzWZ6KjyUdo@xfmpdoDLHrq9Pbte2@4fbwd6t7R2cnj0BmVusxsXYRTwWv4I/IXafjoFp/BgYi0UOgvH5@Z@L34/F43GcCAdCvY0Rj2A7F8E0VwW/MJXQK5wjNJrJt0/N4UUpK/GJCmBRV1exdYVqJjiI88krDRpFzLIDD9CNcEIIBqt8HieZY8qrsfu5Vso@2T@wHjp7BuPnckq5lliPsYwq4fGWasX3zYuttVMV2kRWzJ6mY@x@jPaGi@WSJmrcoxpjp1JcrfCzPOOj8sviy9LLJ88Pnh/sCbGTtcs1G9cTWLjX7a311a9BxHg2F2fspBab1nJVf6dbvS6pmxpa2yqyCrD7nlqQMpd13qzrFFDQIOTdL/wgN90swbuWUeFd0/IprV5XNzSWjI3fffl7aDjlYvfT7ccsjpPQf/vHP9KKf/vH/5p2j8WvaGJayxZjEBOdaqEYu7gYX1xcwcXD8rFmjCOVKybBzVdJ1FhdUbWsZVlVVlF0faOYymn3rarix1WLajLmSjF/vaeYj7mXfpCWKUFQsCBDXmIBqyS2e2jmNfX@JrYWNTw0yMK/TcMtx4RY6cmrS8bgpVPv9vumRi5FYZW3Ett8K22yt7gG8lZaY69qdVxDV/GoYbBEsIGHsHCdLF5PKRtxBtoPqzeuqs0Uo0UGUBxfGsaGdXKtrZ@s4dGDRa8NC/6MDZf@MFHg4cJr8GZsfOGKiY2konS7vlGuTYPl69AUNhTAbCNYJeB/knSSfPcLv65phb/941@5bF22PtNAWyyXC6oW@9nPNifWxDW69Z9BwlvMYAQaH62xoL0KdISaIuMGC00/VeiQO6CkTiwUjXn8QG9ETREFC7NvgfqPb8IZCkNUey1uia2boGgbeEo@TaI1WT5KVgUhFEFJdHb6nTTBYBv4BRnozsKF8BUMghGX1YDTCl@ZgwKPEYyxdqflDifOmI5pJCid2kyze5AEcvgKGrlbo9P9PruWgMUpGzeTcpRdohoJTmxkuC6azIORRvgKJPGtfQ5nbKyjIQqMaVowPsgYhfCkgG4D8m5C3kOeoEW@CSo9j5BmHDueyALxWvgKSAxEBRMECWZuQoQq8KKvAAGgDAkfsNlkmyybZBdmKlWd2@O7wt3qaEVRDw7BC5gMoXXR6EKQuIrxwAvEevy@HLYLv4ZBhot4BkA4DL7iXQPFAJPTG0pmZKXivUEBLLIIlaCisXv35ljVamY3yahECP/UHOMkF9WDtRxXABYoVR91K2KaoaXDauAbNjugeIrQhVYncROH1UhSJuLrlSDA/3s3WmyR16qKAqpYAL@@eK/oAMkgMZKd12GHbdaYqhWTLES@A7h3CCk6ihxqiifTj2TtsyDwCjD8WSz4egMwqOPoxKHfbq9bQWAwUk7QdD7awuLMwLdewK1dIaPb94LUYSooijmk2D3TAS2GluIDQ3uJrJrEZHPDhIQH7UHXcrh7W8sn8UGpMDaDp44G4/x81sjQTceGCnXHtkUW5sgCDm6zhxYBPMo3zsXRnljn@KkVv24ocRQjlwxzYctHjMliHn2jltLiWnjbAVU3oE2aGX2ZdUZdppVZghoaGRGzQnBJSkQIt0EkRhq3h8YIUDoyDDo55VYUpQ8S1aRNltSemNCuBnsmjDaWq/ifA1bOzVNTOUZT8ZLdwwNW3C5FDIUw7H582d23Wja07VM2NE8NPh@cWLDq4TJQCkCuTQNl5z8gbAX3c2jZNMtAcJrHgl8RHkXuLKUjadcSs@TNZ1ZdS7SwRi9p8DEd/NTvmW5F6EvXpeDrwe7MDewCkXUbeJdDlmv4FkFqcTzrH5q6EXwLRzUyriPjOsM4AVppYBkIncLYMc4YarQCjjHANDuBjQ3sxVDar9AAQH0PehYaDPScClqGAUycbqIDXc9n8Bb7iGU1ASNys02@iSWAgVVfW4QOYZAUy@F6XagYmSbXka9A7xx1IQxtEvjND9MHrRvdZMxx3rzZmg8OBx3Kq8Z4twhe8pEX7B3YnqnoaxBYAAyXYLKWEFMANiUmRQ46TH89OW/tAvGSCrsJKc0Qgk9qgEKiQvAtcBb5JooAAQ90lxvO9s0Jnp@fy2TjcuKYsuHid0Jc/MC5Mu6bIEbbimeMxv4XGU38Eq8Pd@6S@OeB8LP3W1P64Hz53ow/BaHn1vxdMYl4z43j4HiGn8Hoj8geFhqicqlB7Zn0CZ1Owt@kw9uf1kxfBO2vgu1PKsWvEAhjCGaanqU7aQCWbndO073zbtUPOKMOCcChFo3AEy3POsHLyA1c5rgXxrA95KNhUHt4SouuAEnk87bzrHkJg5iz4NV/H5tTSGQZ52zbcfRZgsKTGBsbcGJGYg@bwbBPIeCEYYZdcDOo5rQxay4kn4bJYVALtCTmoLEr4eJ2oNwmLoZPefgUwqc8fDrPNMi2MW1ykQy9rrA42OrRRmIQE8HMgjhX3H7sPIQgg@zNVA4CY84W/K7g16lR6oDe/A3qsRY0DGgTYyC4kVAaL08aJ03LNc43mimlD41dJEJAjQPoRpNoet4N3Uj94dlwbLsLXhaaxoRRyccbvToDvzXwtoJlDCuIGganl4nWDPsjf7MCFwj8AgMElMMgEEWDbS9hJquhDWYKhIbTEOc05og1fGSaJH35Qb4fiEuc9JywUUDNCCD0D4sEaEIIC3oO/ypUwB1eODbECeJK9CGbEVrVijfjQMlrXYXzmipVUgQrSQrQBLKjuFq7XpQgHKqicS0oUswrv/6j6K99MPo96BfLsacGyweMqhDtKrgFEEQIv7sQVVm9FqlXwEDZ0IeGAyPXLpdP/dEastlQAjWD54NFcM/xU9eJSOV3krx@6JihaImVsCnMajUo4qzGuyXvFwFJOcHDZK6fbBY0BD89ZyAAI7M0meEnm0aTTWs1zjjYdEWy8wiSU0JyypPw2NMVSDb9ZKA97QfDC1ZPE6RT3KMoAjyVD6MgBo1Fht@7xqXvL9DiHy6Q@nnOeQ61Ar8NoYiN7azTXJp7I4J0hGldA4AN8QaALv/AZEW4zvBUKXwLeRQnZcCj@JvfDDivgAZGLLjKreImwkZGOjAI/GKKxgHou2KqIYgqTf7iX4b/xHTgGfzUm56ZxZjqomcmfe3vH8WziZSNdNCI9KFmcsiQUZN5bvnmJKMyRwy/xTywQaprn9sssUTYBn9l4idV2kO7rYx03MKCn53zP8U@niUD/QEXTtj9se3pnp3LVbjSZFKzW5Y/1xnMvmXj1yoilrFB1uvahmvFPajUjt23TNdIMzRaeGr4aofhf75AiMrJvtN2BcGftuRqLILm7QpF3VYLP4TbaiVwk1@yEu5Vpj1/2DzjcQH1X3BF0gN78oEejBN2@wuj4yXvholm3v1kx2bnNHEw9gNxinWbAQ/rgPwPoQOQYJhrzzVHMiGNonTbS9AnGwb2yO6D1DdxZQFTXwO/P4eNCOnjMeGSZjqqtJWIsX/qJYlOWk/6ST/54KTsEy2hJ8P02iKABWKkmXOdxkhZZ0l2rZXZ8WRBfkcfju9RFN@j2/ElLfw6zlw1r/HAD8s6m5hDgIhzNLJ3o4FFB77VvYHOAiqhN8pVPMF7o9ilLWJdxHQbom770eUetI90@ObCW4j4p6vof3sFBsl337f6dPw6@NEM@M0Itz4m6ANDbrACmoDo@0nkPTezC5v2w/fMC@Lit932UIQAMZYYl4XWb6FjjkHtdsMvOASA72jzuCvrRrunrVo1HrgEJ@cszU611VX0sNU1hvrM6Cb8mOkI3KDEh6CwEb96v4IjoyOmZ3NdLwFjVzIMhWEcic4jVVY0GT19lkyublY8ihm2HpopJwz3V9MPw2@wZpziq/HZatAD4vEYTseemTj9OZ6NZ9zA@pB/Zsbno3z84TWJthTuJgjQgY@eanqebfI29nmYCIv0HiNCGFdeLDLaPw4gon2gm3X4YSS6u6RQuZFEtaCWhcVPiyyvcfO2Go@0iqBN8qWl92uSdzW6925zkabGgc1Z2M6HDSE3IOOmjU4nEYXIfW6tMdu6wRPQj@bprBWjSmsJQw1TEqfzTFK3Sb5ICqgZ78MTJ5w@hScC7BteizeooGw4p@V/sI1RyEgfR6QW3weEdIASoSInuY9GJJYQuCH6xVWYZ2dlnp0beXYW8gx7wGKWkUhCZyFLvxawem6rgqHR81ZwZwxC3Rket7FtuCxbd3C24iJuxitmmsXP4hVgyHEjXtlNAFOOd@OVh@Rw45UjcpzGK5@AY9634pfxStAtMIIDr@S4j/4@C8f3Tryyk0heCZ5@arhBvnK8EtYpxNnir0QRIAWWG6RGXGKzbL@YnmPAwEZCZZphi3HTqD7RPEyafhn45x8Los@IYCDOcW5QZJZi6sKgERkxeD4wbARm6pf05Io/mu8e7NGmpzAKZpMCHS@ahsCDGB6LLzIjjhiG0ooGPAFB5JuV5RixyEj2nuj4uUMLpUpezJ@oJ5M80E1QeAMiN@eZ0Bei/PRBfS2C4BX4fnhi4lV43kAnyI4wwjXZ5BK0kKiv4rcUCut6ERe/9qM1RHPdi5EAWymIwmuJwEZ4OshwtDiHmY3t8WIjoVDcaG9G09CkHO@U2HqvJSOu4PfMFcHk7ZcMGUO08ydvK04kHaK2wIIwsJFp8l4WjgvEizFozusikirvfIBChOdADzc6p/T1rYe@k@JxdpOmsWLVMBSk5VkS51pkk5BYRuNUE93juYfK6y6arPow9TVIOcW5lgQCiKQMc@H81f4A@d3m8nsgUAdEuJbBMsF6@VB6U7y@dZS9hvlwnu3NCsTANHuYXCochTnMSQ7aQUQyv62t3RDxccsHF/J5piH0a9J@QLZQJ7iDbtd1Cw4LpQTnbNHzVAPPU201oW5KJMMzORBaZMzJh8MLHmI6L9rtuPKCL6tiDKH5bX34wRXsLFZwtPIQHhXAuUZy3sudiUW7XOZ9G9g290GWqlYYZ@S0XBpW89wT2D0t3YbLtuBx0Dp8ePD08ddh0C0Wi0l/jJ7N8cNei3Ot4TjOIdMO6nA8WKK2aGn8RA4uduN0vDuwHW/txBJv8BLOrEEY0CGXoPn5fTzp87IIP7/WdyEdjxuhqA/rdN4N9AWuhKKOjkO26dPVA4IYXmJD94EE4i3QO03aWpI@BtNqWfrIaLVo@Gq1cPNSq@WPYlg1wYp48mexNWXiOvTBV/4lo3NBICsM7OEBe/Fo@5gdP9ple893PmFfP3jOXmw/PcYD@M@eP3i8v8Pgt/v0aJcJC1sr8atvqFACXR8aHQM/5cm0TCbHCPKOPZ5xvpPYSXL/I33EHtkdA5epNl19dH/AX2TL8Oo81S6oozOcwzTpK38j08P9FvRZOlBjUbjp0uFA3PDPIG4bdNoR6rwju2v2TIgroO47Ng03OE/GhibUIPDb4KhxmgtJ@AU62jpEX5bEHVjnkFyH@Lh2A2B0vv8KSYwx@CfrujLzCRdeH0zB493DJ0cMbTnsHPw/xV3vVhs7kv9MP4Vik@CG9j8SCIkxiQGTeJZAhj/JzQHia@w29L3G9nUbsJNwz@x@2BfY/b6PsK8y7zCf9ilm61cldauNIdzJnDM5J7i7JZVKpVJJKlWVdjZrB7XdnX21tbtHr@8/1XbeED1r@wd7tfVDJHHGd7ubta3aRoU/CAKFnEKQhV8uw@G9KOSQnanS/BUn37k@dX/0ltR6YwWvrhvsJhmqucsupE/Q6ARf/NZcybkMsXyBayYfFajMbGXvzQea85X/G044zVEw2x@kDkO@FXG2oFa5NhosazTeSo6JmpjJFl0@j7gYK1yM4pc4@EKGnz1lgLMRTyvwVWoDNirQfUuMBh7LBjRV9IhgA5QxWCkrvtBobs5bZZBrVFuz00M4TalNjAj1C4q@NqYmJYcppm1lABRODbUu9EHFUvSB@J4@LOpqhwPJoJ5GHySDeiYfsBStwXZELekcl8PdS4hntSwffrnob/GxsHoefVhv8C52ReMk/cZd2lDRhXCIWNHha6tEy8NXazbCZhBwkZDz40qnTkcGhi@XCZJMlKNEtm2jnCkSNm0cNWizN7mjF6nEDbATarSHocqU3Zw6gHGQ3w3kwrCzTqMrJlCx6Q7znlpBcKDyml4@RBdtsZtIv8cMiEv@knhE5Tb1qtB/aDkquX6rxoa2keTLLo0J2vcQWL@FwD8ChgAlLk9pNHmmYs9VgOm1NStnwh5xJPS2v9v5iZ1bl00/UUBbbWV@Cb58cTWRvcQ@ydgpMnbURV/8AS0r@Siz3RvQGGexylcTQQo2z3v9YSB9mEm2gE@ceJqj3JjYqLafDXF1baDDZI3dXteq9JS4@I5aT4kpH1Irc7ycnUfiK76zljifJmGxuwM6jdPelW@dnXk4RLr2oX6hhTCflUP5OR4yJrL@dGLZ8bvCVZcr5bXN9ePs7z97uO9SxIJcN2uMDvGfGBN10fDgcz42WBxg3aVHmrmnLLw8RWltg6elJUa5AUb7wPOA9nWv66UoTcyNb3@HI83kd/747VtZSmUhmfQdxeF5JpZunjoyVXpc5kRpExBLdhKyJOsz5ovHMCN5/RrOM@iFElGkCzmCffvELWBahJjWnV62SbLoy1h1d0fwXbXGFhXxTdZwirH7I/85s15eWHPzsUGJssiZMSLaM5CLrmuZpfB8dQvc5v3gSH4/HNzKvdjJ9PCHoG3eC@0P4ZZduBuWTEsWrIeD/f0esDK5/UNgqe3e3YBlkrwNLeL0iDm92XRkTXt/jT/f6jseewQGcy80KBFQq7bLLh9Rm@jVGSng2mDiBdH@wWZ1b0@lZH9CZUnuYcvQ0mIQsB@p97G1bdBlYZeLFk12yGlZPJkvCYs28@@@wTyVeHeICr0G8TQ9ImERXyvTDkYi9fTMwksItr5ngWgol8Tuq5FB4ZEGfEN7QEI27jSrgc7UZqZl8glC2whc082TtbFtw88W1jJ344rTwdgGZNsENc7gWTK9/z7K@vilqUcWWIgfhAa3aCVN8w3tE/ap4j5lzOWSPXhPt5guhZG9LLDThnYw/CokV9g/zlDMSLIIl7WwJdb14lijJuvjWbPMYYNETAMNWHrqRLFopgQj4vnLqt2hbjzpZZJTEC0ycenla5srqPjJjZ7CmBrRPFmOFuT2WJtlbI4MlifQzmrYpbszPYYt9PKkeJisiqTtvVVl/zlVySyRqMnQfGpjTCJBXl5aevo92JOtMMWzPwpb5pBJ@Tm86NP@PgYZjkNW7xPn1nY8kx4zwD2kE9N6M2AmCtJSZ8qckmg7T0Y2foSL6IUIGcRyxz2ik7W6ajSB23ToMiPZ0DnLrTZYQzhqqIyaW9S/ub86COTv1vfoj9cngw2ZYDp4A6v8d71B6MdeeVYAF@sTXF6T3/zBoMvZxJ/pAlAy7MZ0r7Mde9uJwau0Col83ma3pK29k8Ts1jO6Bq6E1Ys5XB0M7V5pUr2XLZbspm7VtqtqnmM8thO6yNQg5Vqy51HQvQ8BlsGsl8D0wT58j8OX9J9w8AxIIhN782WYNu53cWOK0Kr5iO/y0WahWrYWJ3u/HTYbXcT98FKPQ5XynlBB1sJWd7fcaZr1QilRnpAL@90MlfJS2VyKi9I3KHQBKQlCehPfrQkLnhrGUhLuNWc92EfhYMsfifaMLScb@eJKYfmFw63rekPv4ujFiTffLKcUTb6N7kV4Obhu/XrWO79qq47q/3I6ao6//KbU0jP1lOpafCKBdovL5TzHNn1Of1fUiwJzrkbwFQcNxlW2ObnjU6k5Fe/DS4@U3BLCm@aX8JCY4FI1f2G4EC52w/LF0fJJuVsulC6OuiclOPkNF8rDheJCBh@e0CxKMkZO5o@GJ5hTba2r371SiGfJt0pq1xDFriH05V1jEPS2KztvEto4LACgAtO23qxQl2uDZ2DNBt@TXNe/zmg1mafAsQ4WSM4MewUV4Q/P@mSoY1oBYUa94tFqNhzx37HrzBRyl/1hj1NMZEOwlvoWfHNmjBtTgTUKlOUoMPEP4V9AcOI8GRwMydexWFFni7JcK8J30rVAHKEki8PUcSoFn0Igqn25jk6cMOc3mudAAvdkf@NianWVb80mVgtzrMWDKUdjwA4ThRM84gCEfvp82oAqeOUestuHQ83HexEP8oV1VEP2k2EDeYdXikiB@bf6yv5NXH6VCCCEn5E1V06rOPXKixaS4jvIygWEN0tu/HHMALdK6ZQZNBawpb5yDJwtxZlGqFaTib7PXIOcQiv6p1uQLfLbrWZE@V3JziThc2r9FoKW3KWctIafTlwsYxXLmmIms0WKme9SA5ou2h6982lYjdWG3@kQ0kKLmZgceGT/Xl3/QlR/eIQ6TyLkJT17Kz2bSM9JuiAV58rRBB9nemlnSqW/xvluVCrO5t2qq6x48ZKjnm7maEkS5y3dlzfMDXv1IM68FnWlcGWUsJpIyFopn6f0vqQ8SpSJGDxKP5J0zd@LuucjLBN5Xyfrx6@jO8hn41ltazLBpblu0Hnl6CuWdQrYLEXUVEqK8y2CygyqsvbB1OKEVnDQ8/OwXSvHUBaKRuLwmEmtrb5O5fQi41VmEg3xYrw1sKaMEYtKXOcCE27EDotUDyc/skAwTDCaMiN3zRQe68JjCyxyPTLVihfkrQFOTZsc4mX4RX7DHzPYk8iZfOnpiTOC@UgaL97NSQKx0H2Umk6mpDSBu4h81I26ZxaJ6x5PQpwuJHYsLXBUpy8@2G2owR9FcsIWFEZS3KJ7lKIpHWcoGva9qwuReOP8PT/vvGnQGrvf8Ueqgm1Gg72wnISD@9APhyECQHEcm/Cy3@/g1JEXfNfsQq1jiSwu4bglhmjN7DmnBsseye/hSTukU6Gc2gXkaxiIxAnh5dkZnMngAdu7hmiFxiUY5pxKdywKDRozTxfFzdxXCL7BArgTnNlISM/J6AGlw36j6eccWqOFtPpxpKntQN@@yfp0@I0gxBhNaS8d58@XQfPXjTc4z31eLDwtWiS70sfBhdzTZ7GDFRHJJCwiPOBS8ZnjWGfDTTkbzgKgp7Yx0X8g3vSv/G7Xdyo0Y3DGkBatoT@48ls5x9nzo0NgwAUr42QSfti9y0FTlDu06GoQM8JLOPTkOIw4DL@Yn@W4uMlnZZ6DQ6v4tJm6@ipogYDG46Tdw@kwH1ggTIDQA4Uu/CERZd5VSZT47FnjwmuXCyiiiBqIc2KdTURk6PaGQZN6hjVZTodAyTFIXFm3NYEJ1dfsNOAcnJuGANxjYgoYBMxR0n04OPrQ/A/hoHTDzBl7w/RMnqRfj8cKDXd/EJD0jQnMvcLFLNypgw/e1vbV/u7WwcfKXlXR8/u93Q@1zeqmWv/EZ9w4KOfYu@rt7jZJl@g0XU7Nd@lDqrJPJVOc4FR2PqnqT@/3qvv7andP1d69364RNAK/V9k5qFX3PVXb2dg@3OTTd4KgdnYP1HbtXe2Ash3selyrKebE5dTulnpX3dt4S6@V9dp27eAT17hVO9hBZTjVr6j3lb2D2sbhdmVPvT/ce7@7X1VomLNZ29/YrtTeVTdzVD/VqaofqjsHav9tZXt7oqG7H3eqe4qNBKxWrlcJy8o6bWFRE7dzs7ZX3ThAg@KnDSIeIbjtqf331Y0aHqo/Vak5lb1Pnga6X/3zIWWiRLVZeVd5Q41zMt@hCvXLxuFeFSGSQIn9w/X9g9rB4UFVvdnd3WRa71f3PtQ2qvsl5Wzv7jPBDvernsJVg1w1wSBqUTo9rx/u15hutZ0DmjMO38PewaVO/kiEISwrVHSTCQwzCLSWiLS79wlQQQfuAE99fFul73ugKVOrAirAomLjwM5GFRIRD@xmqp3qm@3am@rORhXJuwDzsbZfdanDavvIUINBxidiHar0kFuNfiK85JGY1TGc63F3qtqWqmx@qAFznZs4YL@muYXJtvFW0zyHQLyWEiXoQWfQuLAVK@3bn658RKC8rZGZrqOJIiZt7G5WaUbW8axSccIhzTorE6GU7DSaaaJEek2ErGn5p5dn9aDb7sHHNComio@L8MzDrTouriQ5du65VErrV7hAOl2vf6jUaaO7X6@73kNKJtD4XgmtBr8vl6vbiIsNsPOG4uflS6H7aoJQa0/0QScb6uEAAjmF@k/E9K1x4bsqn2/5uhic9wHYqI5COTY5x1EKiUZ2dsRdKnGVrJng90CzAxfMGPC5Zh16UlhGcqZeSH@63@IXmRysDySdRd2Vz2MTy2gEX3xTjVTCIRH4j45IELS5ylzo@7@eZQp2ddjz5856vVbGdU0ZzjukfeBZxv1O8VP/bKJ4drI8I8vHzvqygNDsu3kJE50/a5Ip3S@5Abcsgz/1If@4BhuJ@QCtKVfFymqttMw8keKwSPKUDm0B9wruZKz53lV@qn3Ebq6w@Kw08f1t9F3GFuwFEamWJrwjLnfCP29PJAMNMI7FQSQJdISMfN4qY@xNoszXlPEcma6DFix/aK4@93leJ5LQQvay0bHrxGw8CEY29iSH3@xV3q0fbm2R6AS2z1aWni@XnCjs1k@e/H5CPRxOlqOO9Wkep3UaJ1mjZIMWPjxSrDDeMfszA@fzyIiY7abT@CPiPER2G0lLJggyNDfExUJdmOilfNAhpTgAxyPH8OvUkakZIJNoqovWXDRGvMRv0FqJeUAbs3TG3Gsj/AHsaPibIR41SDOQZjEOsEucS7sLlnupLWMqypsbDtyDLLmU4WMJ4xbRgFVdbD8L71p@07xt9WIopowYr9ztXJKQeDSJhTJ2FV0Z2e85zohWAHP0MPryk@Y3evykA9xxuLtGOKwM94mMW1FJ6KljZbRu9JGGfIL7MxBUzdS0qqDldzVSPPa0OjkKDGKNBkYFF63AxjcJuBTFEZmski1gX8@56qtwKoJ3AE5Jc6x@J86d1hwNpWTih@h3E5VCCawoyIlQ7TqqwzFZPkVxLAw5E2T6IXow/H8hTabAX6UdJ0GPqWUFAXwQJRmq0Iq2r0yU4NocNFinGzE17U@fYjA3dsecRw3Tpzcj8a8hEujeGZsPnzjsYTszhQBgcig27PEbmaSdN2jr9Drl6uI4J@k2L/oZpecKM1XcgptdPvF42eWZsxW8uMoVXZNV4TYVVa9l43bKo562TBNbefU4TAk418T/yM@zAiQa8Myl52K1OslZBT3KjBzQoZasCacVRUyiZenNnad288oKkZmQ/frkyxCKQK8Bn9vt5MtEekrMc5MRF3kmVgccBQ9Bw7FNxuSjQ9adsiFmxwecxy1WhuC@keE1JoiOQOdQfTE0lXnMhiKoJLY6jOMMQty6OSItT6vXEfasmQSHRtgfdiVavS9aLZMjJwE@NIa2u3xOvWuMCeXOw5otLJaf3@95sF1EZaKW0OVxt0qz1xvQ0rGBdhOOXjB2c@qjVjr43fByoOMX0nwWDLRGwiz6qRosm2T3ztOMBIpn1MJgCG@FVo75g5t04cNCVMKTjLLLKkPMa3h0zSgdg9FCUWVW45RVogmHJWUirqpl9e2b5BKC6pChPlMwCKPNBdtscj04d4iG33Vv8CvmfiyBui2/FUUmtUCyLlA6qdblGI/NoTS93wtZo0FdAQ1IRImiKNIiQ1Wao59rdtJ2Tak4OiZil3JL/ng9EZMaaymqKGZcXTsx33KWOhNUWtShQaNgocXFJUZl2obr5s7NGEcLTR5bq9RxNxIpL2URUX5slo54ErkZPX3Ck1bylx@HGD30BWfcegkKhLFmxbnqbTnH@MGm4GPgD1q2TpRWMq1GH@o33vr0usyLRnWow/41G8PQH9MOoJkPRnmGUc/8qXferW/0Oo2zoBc0aJ@GWO8jkXh4HPMjOuxs0LsO@dogTmhZmVrj@Fniy0gYNrxH55IlKzRXOPT7GdtMYTgYV84lTARrzmEEGN/2yfzdn4yRFpV5thQXcpL@p2yPV3RLd5Z9WpxWWE70AUALuLUJCwrxIR2yY5LlfFq6leH0vgwWjqcqqxruHRZ7CYxfEIn4GCaBsUHmllmC3QjszO7E@Kg18locg3CAQEv@po/7bsIMf/YauECZpMgrWAq8VMWVglVUTlFGiEOIh/Hd5F58/i/GnhD4AfSLT6dxyzRGYBHXNtGWQtmv6CijhAubBwYso1kSkxQLzoKu5X7IN02MJqEmk8d3UYMtf2hRpMPs3eJKjMgMbXxwu12mTiKnPnYxqcypOZfjdmAJUhlmCnczrP89@1ke/DjEFc0ZBNOGhpyxkL6LVE2iEq6onTCvtVGWmMrfHzGLiw/ttQkClqeZnFlXJWdSZuXCHiiBzK841uoNSBinJqinTT3mwmGvP/dA6t0pO6ZGZptG66brftcQWJitTJPlfItJWx7jcVxyJvGZYJokxdjSjHgI21d@jth8koijch3jrVwff4cOd9EstpuKJpWov1sy9jEpXsGi10w00ZBi3BGktBR9P6pTw@t3SxANU7ZXdZYYdYiM@lgeLVATZIqo9HAKMfdp3Cfo0SLKod4W0c7unzuJOmkkZ0KemqREkEvQE4Hb4bRJcqnfhvEFwsTJCjcSUtGCc@SN@SivmD1FkGEkCECsiv1srIcSDW7cWRN8xLcDtDN1WAsVIYnoac22cIiC/kcE46j8WrmjLR7q42zxpCSQRhEk2lVwrvsgGX9zej2qjxjKLVLQEJ9CiqhFt2TT@cNb9aNtoXwEQUpzsrb0LXhojKsWCBv6YyfVR1gDx1XpkokRlRwIdRYNNBZol3LW8WW7itVfMBCOh3WDHka0gZDPGfws6BII571ciKiNIqPWGFlcTW4Zba7KrkmRmKHkHeTXQ1GWurxxJQC@YEzly0WCgLCmjD0OBTj0js15CUR1H1HBchHDkj5yVNTYznNKOoiqMzxbsnIUpuV4YcPITgVCC4vpeWJEaM0yPUsMhSa6qbhYOZ5Pb0@cgxbEhveF4tQVuleSNIx6TgjIFzcX3FiiHBWVV9AczInPltxEYsTfnPqiYKUWJlOJPhGGR9niZOpKIZGaqHZxMVk0UZLo4dq1JhKJFK6NcCQVfuwfu6bYIc8jm1Brk5FYZWj7bFysTbtM2rflfgnVKjtlmzWGgWd7hpvtV12uWEkEZb8/ALua4yMDxG7/4dYay1SDib4rgOPSGWeXjGwIecWawlSPZmGnayLtRQEKzJ6211YfDra2EmFfT8fG0OjCHywVCgUw8akd/N7YVkOVFPTyydz59mWnk@9f/2nw4TTPst/3@UqAl2YH7VOX0KAIc73BmdwMARwoK3JntSMr9vqX7bZ9BQNOKNF51G2SU0dDUDwBBZHRy4cDVgAxSD3B/owGon0/q2j0XTdkoamhmGMoKg2T4KuUOT0j8uBDG/bZ0UkVA4NgNtZMNG@55bWvmEFwswl3Focvdr/G5smpt36n0/PUR1w8jEgBMzeTBba27AIFyYITRvbuvQw5Hq2n/KugY/kVI4vN6wBnJiZzz4SJC4/Y@Hv@WXXUz6SOPqdoWqEmL6CZC4hP7anUWcrVweIfAFb4kNB@UO6LRj/TZDpNZqapXo/g@Ikwelr0pu59Ellc1olpmn0/N4g6Hd0cB2ugpru8FjCx7Ll7uSV3ZI@ImzoeFdugYUFgaJwQc@VhJeBq9q8Ti1fDdvthUpGvAZCO/UMSUW5C@TGByGcAPAL18CN6Ior2v2VpWG9NBBSRBQ4u67gtd1CgjgKO87hZ/u06U6lU1Gx/YUFVKuv0kM2qynpFbeLD@rrapPd1vD8pLy4tlUTmbrpf6eO6@Xij1gkGazgXmueDTXqltDL8xmCtjS6ezZdnvdJsvby6VgrzR5V1uPXT09/@/T//9h//la/ol//Byzq/HH2OMuVyufxs8@vsk5sS3o82T@ZmT49m@ydzZyVw2d85anivNsw2YvPR3ODUScssYH1lO1Kzz@boM7qoMhcBXjQGv5J0eanSzTCf1l9DuTmKZWy66VvfffhRntIW3lw6MLmVJyTSBHQMdTz1TtOHAR7NN0RJwgV2oFJezlaM4h7hYKIM0alKWkfi4TXrlQ@fljiSAnxxacbKBt3Q70IDfsVrXmme4zToNxjWNf/mP78Lz9Z7IzV/nFHzBTXvqflUin@Kyy/oqzubD@CdK9loO5BKeZQSHy3AzFCFAS/0eP/Ad@1MkNtxZvnKHkAyYSo4s3jBedHuj51l5MK18MyZwX2bSlQkfMiEIumvs90b6pavlOMmlXC14YVCXe9iuDLrRCXqXyyBGqEYAsQ1XwhBXvaoSpz0sUcynvLmi@5rh28TYsAg696bLR73@EBz0WxX2zwn9lK45ojN5@Ur5saSOEMz2kiR@mME@EBFtpMF9iScS885YuVttZKbKV7Ydvs084mtw9gfGtt0KfS7sphArLltws12tV@LNuSW4xWVCqLjFauq1KTtt3KsIheXnWHQ1@4KXDsG1NeothsZSehRBiRwJGb/y9sjjBUFJlLURLfIZVlj1eqh6TISuto1nTrYzcnJkUWE/OcMje1vE2PbzbOXiGEH4QFGKjLlazeCTqijrgyY2GeNwSluB2y0@UK1oZybsT4PV6xOYNxrR0jnGDKbnMfjmZqS7g8aZxcNT6V3egeDxrhG0xatfIbNnEstRAgmIIHBp6ue1jyDsLRIdwlTJGoKWw7h8oLOWF@PJn2binxO0KVmKOiwKxgECXZiSvrfEn01QceYq/9AJ9go3xLe0WmkFrEseWFppCGlbLcZHma3ho5jarDHTjRwUo6gGo1Mwwu60CUm2gs@@CVJ3kGMAF13SnsBaleE5ReoH7PTmd9tJCanfscxjv75kpJ5EeOZr6IUayTHXI5ajG@8A1a0jvycjAIhc5MJZ@TMZDIzx6G@zi1tzyMc5Duyxc83VBBdQMcXmLFniDrsBiIsJ2ao@A6MnKqx5T9BaHcaZ4Tf@LoxBisepzOvHuXdo8/H3ZP5zHH32/EXlzHRItnMslmV1ofZRmLpsUIzY95LvBqrtNCEGjzuJjMcd5X4sFgkIETymaPP@ZNveULoOI2L54/TQpBElwGT/P315QE@fwvNdBKLfNqZcedd0/mZV0VX0dzKv@hD@eDKL2FhNpWspqd9zqBNoNhP97dLcTkJ8yuLhWeLxWe0EzrzR9mBf4n5NhtenvojWkqE2M7S1HP8JcENCULcjMJGiT6OqJ1yrYn4noTaSUmLUD3MuR4nYisqkxOeoPxEZQ6XChcXN8rTwOEjNvyeIpYzeTkWlJgOWtyXwfwZ9i5QTyOEXJv0DhGOhJWB2IiwCjULyObylbs41DXDZY79nHJqA7FbGQh1bz5tzRbdXjerF2tubq6ERTS8ZjorhZXC5Bi9NUQTI3RWL6bmHqni2qvnf/3v3d/Sw/TaYv7jgH6H6d/SyytpeaQHentq3q7Sa@lVZFu@SY/ztAemx@d//V8qv/YngoOU8Sr9WVsysJbH6bVsmYt8S68t00NxcZHq/b@//IXaMCs7NtzFOlv3FCNWMhTZaHSZdyld1dBK2ZbOxWKFHbMAQywMaW9OLzCMGi2uFFhNl9ZWFVe@jnxl7FH0FM@GWUM2FRJNhrGnoJWRFCijgqyANCYUbWXZbhizDTBvjKb6@XFuOaQdwM/anCOqMjLdeBzCZGhWtkXUgRmpkfbz8rBWeJWKzDtepoxNScksIbG107J25Wnp/wE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/01hmj)

I copied cmd.exe from [NT4 SP6 ISO](https://winworldpc.com/download/f0ce02e5-cca7-11e7-a73f-fa163e9022f0) and run it on Windows 10.
Command line: `cmd /q /c polyglot.bat 2> nul`

First OS/2 is separated with `-%*==-*` on line 3. Then NT4 is separated with `-%~0==-` on line 179.

Answer (score 2):

## 343. [Bracmat](https://github.com/BartJongejan/Bracmat), 15550 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{

















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8;c;>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogrl61k5:4op>a>std[]!![ ]?42ore>805在ｕ92g=1\'\0C0       
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40XHh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt1S36pStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKJMACQIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3i2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HbGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr7uBnP4vhxZ7aw1l/aHvMM1yPdR3z1HBkdm/G7uqmm9eygoCxtp3@ZGRYnlsRYkxlbKhb/YneN1jPHHqGk2auYbC2MbTPIFxjbHNiTVyjW4e3LGOWccb2rI7ZBQjMs08My3xjOBCWY@y@MbwYXXisY49GutV12dgxLY9C84w91eGlN@mcML3teo7e8UzbgqACY8@soT5qd3VG0ceOwRMVGYDqnFCaxZASY49txzUgB7tjuK6NnmXw1B3TfrT95JMr8dUM@0QHpMZDY3ole1Vlz03D6V5NobHPjh48uOqbZZ9KtsUeXEdJzbHtiWfveVfh59l237B0psllWbsaWABiesawlCllFoIg7IHpQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQ4pnTUZtwwkiup7ueKbVZ2emN2DewHTDdBTbHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU1IZPd8KADa6rITY3ZmO1C1PkzbGs4godExeyYmCfAAgHglvIHB4Yz0GVSm5UEjYDpzAY2hEUBLCjGIf99oT/rMnnjjiccAt67p6u0hAG3PWNfo6ZOhl2ZtCANikv/ZwLD8RgvgZABxZHOsXk0INWPetvVul2WgvQIeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPbAeoBrECjHxg1H55GY0p1A1Uec@usHwmA@G7oQ9iqw9d20dmETUMtKBPUp0h3KeO3Xf0EVCjaxBNP9t7ytyO7cAb/DAu7zc3genoHtvcZPHdJ/fjrB5Wi@y0hbCKauwcqiAWBLJTfTiBFhKtCRvqxwlTC1hl8bV4hcWBLFqG5XIsB92zxLQ8EEnNlMEB/VzLqvArMK3Ecir0lHw8jfn0HL1vDg0OpY9QitjAtTzT4J7Jsaxa4jH79rDHo3UosyLLllihyIp5VoR7mZU1yA1B55hazsOvAD@AVgZUVPhlcxzQvN1DO8W2tsN6@sgcznzoBL7D8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW4hWF7Q2A2gP9FMBLQ/MEuY4RMh6sQgUeysaGQpwPWSvP3h1g9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaSeOFcAfGcOgnGbiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdPcEMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPH44HetvwzA5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZ7CnCpQCdlg/FUZYHnOE5dndkYMikgUHZxH7n7TBhBSwmCRxxkVsC@xpCe4QhoqMjK8OObRBjCuCYnswgExg3DfsUx3niLgvZuMSB2g4O6zBcdA3HYRgXZAE3TbzKnbRd4/UEB6Q5Xj1gfgbwyJ5uDkMEqEPqHnFSeMZdyG@2iHbPsUfUa0fIi4a2PV7B94HznSGgh/aZMUd9zhj18XgIww/4G3z0A2TOdBJQSJqJ5soRgkSYrjMwASBlBWzbdIwO0d4vOqTOAoNfRLHCtPqdLEK5FxmXsmxsA892MY01GQ4rMGAYHZatK13jVEEfPnYtjlmIQzCawZjkg2jrIFwg5oRFCOmOJtM4eRTUrGuPFovGGdVeWPSBiSPM8EyfQe31gEcZU30EIhBDOcOCUXEELYbXINYECHlYrD3Wta24F0I5c0AagEKHJSGJA2nimSMDxEUbkmCN5whpZJOEWXsGTZmolZNJPuSYXCGULFwlFPfIRTx4Z4FxszvpINUwb9OiFgTjjYvCkmPoXe4neA47Ptbh58DAOPZFYhkdGPEQUYtIbjCqGkB9X4TpEEQc7A3LBTnMlZmJAiu0/L7dg8Z2ZkLZQUSCpHPYHSICkiD0msodWSCSYwManQyZyTrjMQN/EDygeT7IlGAst1@Z7A0EDgcgi3UmjjNj0zHUhDmCWF7H7vWg9b4xxgMAwUZd1pl1oHtCJWPrEbo2caLOeLGY87d1A@JYKN3tPP0a6xtAdhj5eyjOY5OfF2A8piIQKXSLSwWWDpTCInTGMyILgAlT9GxbRv@ubbjUWGznJOz6mJlr9KlrQD/rzZnRCKUcaKUWSWdd4Dx@90L4mKGwtDCYld8KPjEs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE63WQ@0kogsgAKb3ukYY89vJzaxM9OKCE77D1BwIl/JBya7A2H9Ltu80mogathyIkIBCpKI@tiX53Tktb7qA2KCZcxld85ZhrNr2UOM0yu5iy8xzgIGL8UVOIypS6AUSUxi4iErQe5odgbICz3kNiS4QG9zJteLD37R7J0Rk3ph3oiNCmxHkJXQC/FYDUOC3/A6IHk8RFj1BQ@MuuBxC2jdHS2BbIdIDrtRX1nRZWCKtwEd2Za9BCoQM4SLURZDqC6oMR4i19CHYWOk7uIu1BEy7Lk2jgMZjKHjse1Az@BMZ0YqGVVZpHX5mkwiHCuSoMkvDq0wZMRxwPdwFIQE4yHob9TFsKeCiKoDpwAmxjUN4Hk2zzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEsty0ApV3dmHAgUD4ZnyGjGTMcBNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6FzIWZEc1O@vZi5ji96ZtM3pVXWmg57yK1c41R3WQ03GAaEDOlEi3nPjySr5U8pIkKjYY0@hpPwuQkSKJEOVJ3qgHMEg8QAYzeHM6iTEhS4mppk48XolMQkOTMhlNPYVfexdxe4V@GGjGZ1Av6a3KuvD8C1JcJfQjzDBAEXGAN0BOQM6IYjs5XK3rbML4B6glk93KDUKl/RU5VyYl2F1w7x8QiAu0fLKPAvX6ZBDioxqWAKMTiWnQWKBgO9JCUoogoei@GMrepC0x8NIruGeE4smLliCiyJJdh4K@TAAJAgZE4QPs2N6LV9cuXMnEFzWajVobCBNAdvsJqPqQTDDIwOnhsgySSN@JrJnH3rYNxJJKC9GvuTYgNgELbVWZ@fewIEeR@@XAkQCsgoWtuSAsH49PzFPJt2rFW2hJ0YSsdeB0GR2PLEqwODPe0PtJqrGF6gKKkQcqYqNF9MT6GuNl3yxQkU/mmO4KP7WfFQiNZxADPy2upREPKnvN2/QO7PO0BcJuAs6O@dGbUD/xJ8RCBlR2pcJgk57radyINgdOBz2dPvoYc3vizxQaZtWZcFjaHf0IXmvY3QxSPto797B9sHXWktgDM125aqHYuZKBRxqJ1Opb02UnKxV1qMw5oDvt26GjQkX44iCH8wkexoRlWYdGFymATn3Dz69ShKQhJAclAO48XdFpOFxQOgS2ro7uDIIs34qBVmGSYK4TNpjAczQgahjuB7g83Ty5g1W3lWkxr4/Yjac6BxA4KnsWUE6GQOvCGBBULvHR0RKC1KoaeHM7NwVjRng8wlKzVeRIVE60mQ@2X@we1AjsP4khURRFNcDWUp3ujK0@eGkawjL4gD7A1eHpeQ54ihPE65LCdzpLBB4XrdsBXwAgLqObDNpOAqK5g4A952rZSNfqRO2AHonCFflyqg81PlQRCN44BDXQZV32ShKAfPBKvRaOmKFoYvDViefN4q5cnTY6szz7EaB0uwqjAOB3OhA0IkroY88lyJ9sdpH//DRNcRdEiJBFZACzNwhkykvdyig9iKZLO4qO6Ch2UNDfk4cT2RiUlHiwQSr3HFJ@YzE352aXiKT5E81CXEh9@3tPe1@ENmf@6OZDFIaUBfHkcnp4YJIx4U2YtlDu2@zDUjDpcMgQxCbVhZzu29b12pIR08sagzXVID/4sSNPoaxxnxDiiOliqqrfHVGt9wz4NJqIYtEIgoRKIXiy6/0Ux3INS/34d4XuzCIqPlMJnRn6AISRNIQudDVifiSB5MgI9nHZ2kBw/WVa709CJAiCxxYaJ/RhQm358FLPYljysrS@EtR@op9jeKv7NmVpgU@vGmBI0KyvSdPH@092X28/fmxp@XzC@@5TLkAhIP82iALyQNON@ytG7xrYrEQXAz6hoPdC7jABBSUYNp94jrAuGWMInMEVrQavjKV@Io9sOJu8mphzjBUemV1eBN6jJ2PR/UTgqLdHaIy4vDlPRzPsf0MPG/sVhQFevlg0pZBaVVedeyh3lcoHQwMw6Giouqyt4/zGu6yFICMOzN4Cj65BaLDjGYQ9eHIBuWFFgmRNbAEB0@zVkOzPwBdGFcSDScphy2YSqN0QUMAXVkJy0YMmN6Atv4zqCeRN@2PVK3E27Wa0XKKGERb6P4Qd61ngOqUgNEKSJG88sqO7xzfYTPg0gjpKpAYkzdoksNlOBYMGQiSNGuKen5AHOIWOF@KvIJo9HqCs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpXmcgebYE8CS7R/MGkVbYczu61ZM3fEeALMh9H0NRs40Xx8dWEwT04zuEGy7gNWbNhtpMVtn1JBt@/GQVWu9C8bDtBh7QdskJTZOebAU/6@rX2VlXp97VZYo3GvtjjjRmj7dBkHpjA7/uGtG@hwmUaKCysRBXwchvlSUTQkNMKuANKaVAh4KRFpqegnhJIPSieAgtB/hWJAGbz2bwcvAF8QgfQaUb271px12a8Ue5BmdL3TEQkSabO8ilXZwf9GB0DFs@cmmoXGTS7MyI4zy67vLZSkjkL5YG6UFXCyHQrHw4I22Fy8DQCCgVqefAOaBd4bTpYD7LiEo/tDTIkHDCyQeQICxaPegDn4HEvCDbvCA8J/JZLNKJZZ9ZCK1tsJLUNj0@2W9PHFw0NLvRskH0rMbjADQqXISv0@pi2@jwWVaemEoBSqDORsbIxqkEkK6IFRhUBJ2vTKIu6OKMNXSrjITLLwBfYnd3gIt1DD5fJI1QiYImtcvinqNsS18ouvQGWvMNshUWfju6tE6VfhQQYHGdmGZJ/BlQkk7sEUV6TvMtGHgvEHeF8cwbQImhhYl6zR4b1lWdj2uEiWSV1nPjcWD4ppU4j6@trcUr8Xo8Da4tcG2iawtdKXBtkUsiF8aT0UUp0uTC0AalQL9m/LIRQJ4mm9gGpig5vDHHCb1RqWSbab2h@k8Nn0moCqA8xJbwAXDiyVoNncmkWD/DNRuQ3yNl38G2c9hxzLFPgq@AQMDffRpkiQig3qM07xhV1E1vpsio5oDSaKCImXDix43McfP4/LibOr6MpzF1sqrXQD8E5uUlRnLfsSdjENwauYoEvC3ZyFaa1XYtnolvJBIlaQgZ6cnkx6VkSue0TsQNaFOJ4@M4kNSnTqMzcAjeNK0lkyGhAI@eCVrGcJiIy@clyL@dbCZTcUibjKeBLdficaBLB4ngUqFxRoA3ogfmFEgJHROGuOiaAjFIWpzC7vqFMR7MnGiEcNYNpGycQZ8v@uPeCOTiUS75hqePCnQLmn4g9/J4INzi5B3KS@MZ5@4Cx/RYWdiyEoy7p1JvZHu68pkMSpMcGS7ja3FFkmAkpBAOiYr92HSxC@uWYU/c6Ezj0glQzB18jwYTYJbBfp40tCpzLBidgc3i63cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQC6HRl@yERRKsHFEpAuaGeGCXyR9rTQrIxKSHDWE8zN5wvj13KYW5XSsAxmZPYt2zEkIAmkEGgbCm1iEurM3wmzRzNf19Yl/FAa0lDxNg3giA@Gtk605ew6sh40HkXSg34OSQ6MrjAE/tED9ijzunCMrrIh0Cqt7QxghIDSICfWwtoa@QGK7Y67sjeFpEICB9xoINfuQOg8Y11N0wqdfK8ShGGrAGIPoJJQK7VAxQ2CJBUCk34l7/JpoUBHf7J/f5fPndBgi8MrzqO1RnZ3AnKlrzcdGFY/zXahPZmWPTKBDEH6NyfDA9v2uJYPL6tmZrjSbI4mQ53mfK5Oy9yYrmO37SFNBd2UdB5/4rj6UOeTUEHo9mePQdZ/dnRYkyuRSIp@Oroxb5yHXJ4tp@dedM2R1luD5SGXN0xxPS/iuBVsk0M24wcUMGDib5KDOgr8i@gfdClcQ/H9S@g/wg1yICv7swj0Gnr6EcsUETfN4c4h3/NczVyi/0odLIynUjwuOM6xPVc18j/1er0F7yx5n0jImoZz7xx5881zCzpiFKU8j4Q76RbiRAEVKE64oe5qPJ95hXsNBsYwWEE8AMEEV8lgbB@i@AS6CUrifM@bAYL0GBdDiEPjEhvrgKzpXpu2gD41lnhsIbZG/QTGMAUlF2FdYf4Ud5V6imX7S5Mu5542qPY0e7JZ54vZqDo5XGtT@OT7egtAbNarwQalVdEwp3g8jEZQCTdIQcWk9ftrRQ13Y7g0py5QkqrgKqA1TLWMdDwt7jYv4opLZOgx8fh4@nFG@xzUD9xdtn5H6RtVzHAVvapBSNwXVdszJoFgh7H4/HRnAOyEpaaLpIT6mVg9e9iV@GIYtAvG1SisIH8vQrjrzd/caJhOsOGNdhzypMhGI3vlrsG9UqX16xEiu@tCQNBLztnFSfr0gjVgZDuV3fHQ9JrsUvbs1gBJ4k0c6@o@PC5qOo4@cwV/K0uNbR988lkj0@QQhJGOC1wlXovTYDsnyMcgD@H@WnDhhhzP9GjApw0HJpZXlQGpKa2FAPoAg2dQZWFGfokQ9QvjYl6WngEKacJAzN3ZKM2M5KXcG@qeZ1i8zfFVxtXk5stBfjY1yn7LX1uosAwtwIAAamIYoFhlh0f3dw8OZGi5biK@iws1FeiOemcAcsiqQgeUjBa@wj7uxtnHmCaJ2rkAXQ2UjJafHhp1FRo9qBmQO7KIvuEkwDOJaywd8KZlLUrIBTGfQLitquMRjUJgCSMJZSJglaX4P7O4RuXjWYEWnyJKArkTdypAWzMpTyzztezCeELiKUSJc50UhoXaeoKY2rqapNbjmCNcIQZFimRDKEGjwaQ3wPQgssiazSpf6oe4qGc5faSuKFJV0K7fmhpUfQ28QXIhCH7y2lv2opGRys3U@jJQtIfM37DLyx@BixAWQbvG0mzXE9Tfr3VkjgNf8uOM/BlpzVd2pVfYOneIfGqZogf7oojp0Daqxe1Qi5utoJMhK6EZFyxIwBJi/nZqv81SOHF@UG0wGXkkkuw8JLqGJGcXF0RDtq4xoiG4VMYr4zJQMoExPbKhNI/8rdRRIYB6q79fBPvssSAG2tTigiyGcEldOb0ihEqnYjQdFwJN68SmZZ3Q1crIah4FvzD16GR4PWXPdAd0W4ga4sDjaquwc0ftHt2WRKDVDX/dnDxo3twXeUFW1JUDetAU@pKcF/eKLGTbNnoTq0@LjOhm0utbYkrlEkXutdvmqqhABNz@FTyXRAMmhe1Zk3OyGuzNxhkXGI@AcXElZV70q9uM2ALdYXTwIJX//K9f7wL9r9fOAAYKnGAMHS0YurGmpN7KyvKT4gvdllcsnwefDE2dCEOu20B2dAeKpA9Dx3LQtNYuSTD8j3DlwK9xaJt4A@HwhmbGMecLf8FzeSbL1s4sYJmdVXGvbLviWdEqD@hvXSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYEz5SktEk0Y2djtSwd4oRo2Z1/tg4k34HeTTWyvRHOPvpr7px8zk9bZqgIaot03jhip39JNJ15bGJ/1QTi0siTsvPS31SiAO@Ku@LXQuLz4voGP2YZwNnquizYc25Ywet7UK15q4Y6lNynaXv1FHGN2QgzPk91VRTP9QU@hYTTVzSLf3bIk@dGgo/qYHBbeUShGimVfIPNTbM5RBBh/eysINBMBxap1UKpNdsYI8Hq9OjwojpS@Xl6eeyh1Oj2VTAQrftirxyTIqsL@R9ZZaheHKHOlDSetGnCuZ@bL9B9eihkuXlMY4xYWb06U1N6c@DkidyVB35q4bmvgcj2C1YNXEsz9sPDU7NogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gBN88Idw3TLbLLwVxGxi6ohTiIS6FrOQuwOx7uDF3Rpt6DofEdmbjvNdJIZHsVpTr2Gf5Wig8DUE35ffmI9mYpVu/BnKRhZ6jDOL5yOFiYA8Q5xlsa6pnpGnRbTtiTpYh6neFS/8UuEMzuRWfrbmvWrjm0XXZI95sI1HeACvy@vEFHaWnqlkRz3lH3DTwo2Mowr1B92LeHhVJf0eG2stYnTg/5vv98Xw4XcihVvYVDBeKPban@cyVfP1Gck9sqiA54ObiNNeK8YYhdxqb8JZbVpQPFANfnlpfsQaZEKWWFz@ityBhXVs70WfD8OYaOVaQNho7xjMRpkO4wQbkEDs/hIvbPk1vu5ty678eUroEt3laISOWeDA0YrOh@rUqZllE/MIWaybw/i@oNJ8bEWKpo7LdfGXjc@AYl4/2RyvjFWPcn5HENAE@ghLHe@Jrhe2GN4zS@3chM9KHZMW4XZRaZ2hik7zGqzk/B8RQd11P0rcl4oVYXtDPr4GaSDcZBl7a7C9hhyIfyodItktKCfO4a9LtRY@IaHu4Dq@UymYwvwEQWVhZebtKksmHaVya/L2RMPvOc53FxMc2JOJfnQWSJ7jRcyYK0VYo9RS6XFcu0DG@G9/fkpm3bHn5ITQFT7ZooioFkSTtqb6qxa@KOf1aEzacuXJzwaPdWTVrw0cbXLYE@qDTfVOnRlZ/3qk0J1zZHuO60@Hrz9E1kHem2XPCcNs4J8T22w9WypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqt02hjp/TAu5m@CV5eyN8BaZhr8mi2u4fOV2vuIeu8KUxjMgltkFLWVgjAx6vUHK17toUsB/rIw0tfG3KnhqGB1lumt0VkUYm8AXLLwvLBVHhCXPtkC/8nA7H@opQ9ww6vuu4sDB4t5SIu@N9L7BbVncxCnnExa4aYardXPn8qmLCt8o04Fkc@MFq5sEdKoTY@YGz6UAH886UK@T0e3TbVc6fwfnQN@jt6/aqXp9iLUG9sAaGAO@PTx8W9U5oD163PbITagD1v0B7lgbjxd2skfpObSHw/ehJ7JGzihtu7cUp10844oHtD4I7kxvQ4D/uHXyTvc470DHyl4zMCYwLrm2Z48Nid5WRR3iRA@/r@KhwVr0zzuDdKOeDxQJnj8v/Ft1y75ue@MxPVrj4cSlGyWV6GjybXJTj@9Aob2PttOX39ijtux7yv72FFoCX85i2qbXGeDZcN6yjb7d7gzM25BuG7pnmSdKMOXDX99Ld0XKmEy6j97y0ATyOjMZ20stGn6Ij71Vle7PHvFhLXTcIK8sm6Gj09fSWD/puHw2FF2sghPCkd7Iz2hX6JR75fXE9OZAI1uWwuldviyBjlW4@5skVkpWdBRizob9zRMrWykJ6SiQS0YGBB51VbaL29kiXSyb5bdVCEVLSRhFtp98CLn9LT40O2hG5m3Bf6F9LexNWjrIWYNJ373OMPl0fRdENLytnragLcuRKWsYs3TLf6wiszZU8CwjPFsgc02MG9dU8jcuqlA8dSjptgmPFjyg6iYr59CG5tjldyb1Vi7F@VuWQBe/ul7IaTNbrkz7FdM1enwJBF23iYgj28ENxyCDSB1cSccZdGTmXPDijMuy@8DUpSGbRw7irhJblu4GWl794Zgpff7E6Ou4pfqR6eGezCWtgprssl1Et8L@6kR3za9OoGSrGhsaZuDLkE70BD@@LYH3WO@bnYcLFREi6RPY39DJHwvNH72u18XZwHRxR1PouGFiCpscb8TY6lqgNyyJeXXePrRJMe9A/LTj0tjL5tbt8QwPhc3IddO0uunRLKv/XKU6rtrrdSMSZ5PReOL6j@U40J6p6Cz06IT83TMTgEuvgbWygT70ls9UR6ZcQQrzB8W5c5U0/oU5tPvsi1KGgdAGQhgK50sazj0Ynp/ihhzHWtISKe/3XPbEiQ7J4QV7DXVrZJlkWqZ382yO5@HmnOCJheEjBx5EUB7hXb77oRCko@UUeXS7rD8/gXzL@A4t79CeOB0DnaFZkaha4Odq7ASbjPHgho1mUc6iWlrHHkL3AsdwaZfp2NbEk5yJdeOoULhxVKiwaakQaQYs8dXdx8@S0dZAm7Jvk0INUP4m7nA2d63cMHClkZkWCGKr@ehi7ECXuM/NIR3QjuBb0myjzaYOsev79jJ95@kMBpD3VpiA@U9G940OLhvemvcT@7Ft2TAajYFRjg4MfrR/YaPH8oSY7BEeXgf6dG/N5pDArhiEuLShj4021O9w7nqfsYgDvq97@oqhiOYGSf8LXbe2FXPYNpxXNOkXca9SaRcRemhMSbdY3WB4H5S8ToeLxDgft9BHFlZs3LFtW/xO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vf9CuYz77RfmBZbqZ4tF3T/lu0SMLrc9saqsjtG2h/x@w54ky@R7AnTHNFzlEZoyIL9Cjkkgfbk38pDijTxkrhqBJHuqu7RIv1zVmINUpx@wBWigOx0bV8J8xw27cyL2B25h0@EWfr5xoA2EnwLH0jsT37jibWgNR@0R3VYqDJHaPDDaePinTUY7PH16vTL5zJBvsSCyoys85x@wK@zUBZZ4CtpI8vZha0GPWqSqOaYbceqVy@W0WUeyTKPzRsdZM5voNZ@bXgiHMitPyLlirjrSjWgWWdHpQPvSnrS4dQ0EmqEheQMHdH7Fu2l6O7CmsmQ9ZDIycJF5cRVmpehquwMqrL18PT1kro4h@Sb9gJeE5v24fChtr5Q8ETz879/7igKDcKuQCyyMAOu6fQUfkJ84lv94nxb41Ha9njndB7zxFMAqdoLFykMSePCega6NVYWA2rMmQz770I/suxp1SR2TyGqtJA2JXXuGZFinEtl7m14vkc3PdinbaO3UM7qSb@4AVxqkR8ExrzCa/1yygBrljbjZU1U4YaeFnL/9cxlxzwLOAPKW7Uljl57K2H2692j/SB676tLxaXuApyOuyXEL9hO0UiYyJfVKdyLrnXw7Wtd0PeXeoSrtPNqTMcIKevMVDQkeuDK38Fg57@mbE9UVfaUWhKGGt1xAfHj0@FFqfhKTJXYGjj0yktHgncPDNJ40@crh0uBo6gfQO3r2dGXyvV1VTS5pvs8sWh1cxT2X5LQK0pEB2ig0xofc/MqtwlXHHhvdo9nY@AwGT@Tg7ntmX1hZyCf6qdnHXsjKKwlFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcq24YTPVfV5Yo6RW3boofDHyu0oKDlkFSe7XHq4acX/qhTDMv5OhA9LpGaut1bPlKBn9AfoUnT374uYqqqr6Hyo96BeWX5lZS1GWLY@PLRP32Mp2fCVFyn0kjxoVZJ56z7yojQC1q3gDafnfU9wtldug7kJQOhdWNrhzwxrplsSrWXdJF5UIDVuarsxyhfGeyxIhTt8TtHA89I1vnBLPUt0yJm8JeMjJ5JkZ@fe3m0JDnxa3hzrkyfP2FPdRVsjN0eMYmy8B8ZzyeiVhPNWaOhu5XJq1wFQ2o3w@uPl/bnCDnWna1uz6e2LcHTUFId2siEcwsI3imQMzam5bKzq8Hmtp8u3Gd2WNz/EYc8W5OCoDRof0Ltv/QtVzWTIwhA@1Qx/vaVmgg7OEujSZ2i2Lhp0tBeyhg7KLTJ4JJdqo4@MKW5H4bPBy5T6peNb4Yaxr5hcPZzcFFa6ISx3Q37XwtCTZeWMegPA/A1hLC@HwY/s4dnAlnd0x3CX7D9eitBNBSnfUJByhDu/KWVwEpQWFn33ahEfjy74j6Wt9cjwnNx4YLfN3NIybPfQliR7jDbRr4f72yl0h7a39G3/yAd/X57f2cRYmtFj/c3yAOI0J0uDgAkagwkdibgevLhA2gaZ17D6JjejyO7Z3i69LUXyqY071pdmed8c35@MVyMKLBGt91/l4gsRn4OqbJ@57B6eiJtL50tUftwWt9x/lSjLwvlANCL68Gg7aFT7h4oWyXGOxedPF7zxzKi3fxjxc4zpdJWuK01XqY5LQ@a5PjnKLWS7WX9xuoRYq48ZgZQBbDh8Ymx@WPBgYkXtSbtp3yIIP1zLjzS6cmD0O5GwUqlkcvFTFdHzmWh1NbGOVgfX6SwmxL24YGv@@UcIEIMTlf6JTzROBvqYgUc2BQLh1dYhm1pNzZfZFn4fogLSVpJyRC8yARXk1WDr5/5hxkpFvWRrNSZWROYfJw0tunKrpAAX7SlCmZh0orJ1D0LWg6OQjAzsswtGGhyIjGo@A2@yEj0UXvUPiwJK6@dP957uHh5tHz07bGSal/5h0qAQlgW5BUfWP852RSi7TzYYGbiNYjrEPITsyPg/an5uUC4GJbtStNpC0eaFErcwzfq5ZSkKnadVpEvATxJ5bhQKYh56cdhBial@/KPUFX60lU7oQhVx0CLlCXVWYZllGY914HLrlh9@9UMmFIofuqngp24wY9@sLDTbvm13/Rxdg91@BTk@2N579OxglwUIzhvNmdn1BrVynlsd5mf8oZ56Jm0wqrG4nyQOdVWrxR/EgTBxOc4qdAKaLP5CO4doAXXw7LSfeoMl1gk@UDAeVoryX7@uXMZl3CubhLjxAKk4ZAtNnhrK2toaO4JGwu4f7H22e8AQ/9375I0kQhDsCI9f/tmPu9xmfmAFJfjIjzMi3kTWJoToEezgXPL86DTSnLruePWnfshGPR1QDo3jh1/3EAT6dgK02zMyYHbFuFWS7M3wTxP5tseCjKgJBXa2cVoW7Yg5Ljs1XROPRyMOPTTrtdjYcScHmbKT2TZ@xwi/lqTTBxwA9YnlcdM5vqGNGLQ0OWQ5abZOyPLPPYiRiPHNNWjsbQNGK@ZaoOsaXoW9gpaIU58Vfnxekurxa0kC0BVySQNvNIxEvGYHzFWOHeXdr/0zpV9l4PbA/W3fPc3cg7df8d964P5V7n6hYEO7bjdsjksUIbT155eAIxLSH2kf@XyTxU0WzAmH5s0CvsrMEVTTKVEdo/Mc@F0CdjyHk2h8BpUGzQ1qzDdVwPMznGYCjQ1WFAWbFEpQMm0UN6Z819YVo4OFfCGnKoCkdBoAJCvhfTyOygEmkxXoJsKpOa69hOF5c3OTiahGGbVCldessm69yIovQ0TXIa5wNkDkGgzSQJJ5Cgir@8lg8EmpSUyK3CuuxpFxdW0YlSgcRy98t3xCiCwBxOI0MtDs9BS/9OU5s8B4Zhu/jRX5gsS6D0hSYUwiV1IU/EP@T2wPmg900vk3Yvghf9y1yEdAtErn8u/ckc1KbI/y9Z41P5safKrC72sy8gAOKpu5OphG61Z8jiAOEURFXNZ8Gy/YsXdsNRXeNhk00x8sacwWuH9Z6a9os7zc29ctFiau2htEYrG7h5aN@uIDKAxLaIqWVdRCcl6kXG5pkfwS@dlAcdBeygVkB2wKWEbHMF/ZY3d7Z3fvK/tPD69Z5aOY8avRgO/XN1PHkpxuNENHPFqsxSq590A5fHzvQVARc6QLEW4MjN8viXpTSebTQAhyfqzgatGWYXi1dKsxfs4PHl/FN6vdhBoluoaHmvmAfGlrr/SADuhczVwrLaNWPn8TSnN4SgT0Dj9deQ3VRPL8stHcrB9bsfj1lrCkI7yIyRvYCcB17G6sK9jYrxcOCxZ@gfIIP1XlRvtidnlfFNezaBwKD3d79sncLJbvEQmIlDfIBlikICtB1JW9b5/L6HPjbRr/QiY3IxU1khNBuJC5ieIRUEfBxzaRi8xNT/pWFwegcAzNthAYJ@LWFwMjcaHhRW5YKJEU/A8Y8IwT/uc3p5WpTPt4EknkdgQrzW4y5BjASwrQoVG6ezoBReepPeYGrWm99r4RuA5sYL@ghpKiZ7CvTEYQr0ePA4PmzoFzS5AYKBkPUeWyFHAJ347jNIWWMiG/Blpz9Asuj7r5xDQpD4xp1@wDb08k08DRPlbVJgttPWKhybajFRepzua1cGNX/ATPzEbJ/kEGP6dzBPSGLoMiaUwT8bN4stKE/NE/fvb8NJ4Ul7UlMjzqW@LsXrVAGqJfVG/mJLrn987AvOcyblEuX@cS4HcVMDeRFXxNp1yWB65AX0eroeR@6DmPwAliRKI30scsMbG4eTGZ0WviOGGlye6SVOcWCi2WSpFCBQ8KkBml7JGLj98J3ZqxhFKDRoC@rtXFxxtzzBqqLDfBTZkk2Tp@5WoHJC60q5cUQAeGJBUCW8MmBGoGYMQ7icwbOKTBcIgLDzLStiSYPvpDU4w20oRKzep3WOSrZYuSo1guV/wKXeSKZQat7zo7lBUAe43PBXI9UNe3PAI0A/VXFmJzRn6d48Uo3xhH5KFvsgTQiUWsigaWTBjAmtv87Awc/CV2LegrIB9UKs@OHrRKSUVkoemTvmN2cQqcG8YOVTz/UybQTZWFqPEq1@g@wWRoZK7FbaugrbMH1GHEKyw1FiXD1Y8Kz9umqt7Y6v2Efi1AzBwOAP4RsVYADq0pBpsRloQtZ/Y/@xl@tlhMrKvqScs5TcXzmSrc1Gqe5dnH68eStN7I1O6u66BFea@nx6CTKxu5@6fGoNfe6yvHosiyLKcoG@fn8QcbT80XWuH19DKrll6fjNVCQ349bYqlWvqkyZ4@/fxt621SnJ7OXovHCY0@q7uzfyGqOVT0Y5UyO98qZGMnZfxCJdP1/Ambgt7KTtgbuE56DP/J/aYbcevobvfe0Bd@4iKLHR/j54jFoqgojXgT/kndfwkXV/wbdbkubzXfvk02dN2bzphpmmO324WfPQAJUkseMsj3DnB6iq@wY3qSAkXXaNqbzyPoebjVNTwvKN9toQ/ZK5xuG/3@ZFefmZMH3uMvngfXM7zeHCyZkGimUglJalz1rrT0fIxpGe3PfrJ2mT5/2tr8s2@MFGMNH/v4@PblY3QfqvmP19Y@vncvl0trmsbdT794@rXt7e3c/XT@aSO/lZMya5t/@idra5q2qSlrTddVm/HGycnnopbJifKf/Sjeevr0q65bz/4fX39bV/FWhNspKwKfgCvLVHDivQQ/FWWs971ib2LQytXYjP5ascD/fI2p9a3if/vu/uuYF6trynMHnl7sdaxQinEnOOAtG7ydxuqxTYxWuIzNlFqtBs7if/v3kL7@FYCDIbNNuNXzAazCLFaXapTkIlYvgEPVNMj3//r61yMYcjZRIzEuuO6yBlxirqiJW024NujaFNCknJRRlCCe5Q08w2Zq6Y56B19MeIGHZaAJbsM7juH3Xtn@XcYOGqlUqim3JLjkFzhHpKiqdqyqd4AbSB9v1GrSBuM287LZ/B0075ukGa2@DQOmcYc9/8e4Yss8qx8I5ECIFdbuvrxfr0NRsvXsRj1Fl99/qCsVS6Jt3xVZmr2Mg@LRaL58xPsLq4uZkiam02neiaZIIGk6bz/0XfgYv0If7Kjsqt9CEoji@8Y@PF5sF68//1///Ht//l36@x79/hNa2rO6Zk/ZgEin0BHqcN2tVDr1ulh3xPNjfK9D68lUSpWS0ro8TmwA32keMDXzyUU8n40fMupAKmPHSUoNF2Vb97PH93ps7l3nPvWonx/AI5MH80tBjgWqkTuk2rV4MKD6exKlxmm9KaEYVJMaaiHflHiqAMt6mTXuQjWJWrEsNutaXtuHqlNFXnGDdZfZMdAHCwEdfXzr87LVw5D5Wz3qFasHyerzOB8aL0C3LsQaDaVp0DAQ@LG7a5W1UqVQ0ZRW6Hn9YtXrXoZhPHVjp7Hw4tSJzQkaC5vmVb@gKsIXFrRg9iHxhJhksH/gC6BvwbUGf/QPV/iK9zXy8b0pyvVrjVXUDS2r5D8u7GofmL8AwwPrtNvtN502jv56W@/oqqdP9Kk@0732pD1te50Jmsl5/zIJsbeNNXbA2VCTpYLrOHXr9UyWW76THDb@JMmexoTYP8JVVzWVbcCwlIEbyGLkBFUZ/1RVYLFzuJpvNxpvN6CH1lObxB6bdcnHEh5y624zJV1eNsBdrfr/m/XQWaWLu6BwzctUavNFHSSOF/VGCkC@8EHKHKbcqjc3KSDMy8/MD95sgsgipTYbmzV7h36QBC6pCQA3F5CM5@x4wb57NyXD@11IX19vsmQqtS5JazgeNvyRAlI066mgSIhBAiSE8/Of8wfKHXTYy83L@mVj8/JycxP@N@l@6T/B93Lz2j895teKOPPwJmtktVIT2ctxQ6kfK8c@s2jCu6zU0UdWjsFRhyfEA5lCiG2wjRjaTsvGNoTYy3df/s/4O3735e@jpMXgz6gIsXPsGcoG6mllrq7BjVmPLfaYXxa48Re8og96PK6jp8VvFi7lKMpLmVX4bHlCLRWSMg5iLbvXwuPYMnsJUVHkAd7ORK1UEFspdaax2KZYKBJ3/8VrVzwe/ycvtXIxzic28BTxS9d1H0dwC7FjjyF2VcuoknpR55ay@bcLfnHZ9U9@cdUlxC7KzKgAWTou4wQRYlALMUkCVl/fHOE2U1xakFCLO619Lj3blnDaQfdo4ajDVera3m6tXK7zVZH1p9TiNu5vwF2F/901KIYQa7/Gv0dv8I8ddfDv4DX@saM3@Hfg4R973Ma/o9f4t93Gv6MR/t17jX@PPfx71se/41/IZtWquH5OBEipZfVyfSoSIaqxrfrxL/Da6cV/@p1vfCNeq8WlOH00IafaDlOTVSCh68ard@NCrMbW1XU1M8x0MmpbbYPDZBmHZQaZgdoFyaKlsozBMrPMjGVGttoFlwF/GXCZmR7L9FnGylgQEULB5bUyHrp68OjDXw8AOfBn4tantprpMMhoiCI8fW0NwYPronUsNFiciS8N0K9kVc7IBbOJ36hoiC9fHisbTa1cYjI2DLnVeHkcb6I1Y62cY@2ZsXb8ksVcUNCqMeX4WOFTTVBWIsflZau1@@R@q6Ugvz1@bO/P//f3R9HXG/9H@/bjfXtkw//@/j40cKOeupuS7sJVAw7lP7Zi9erWcYUYXMDkYsrm1nE9K6G7kALGpaFf6gOvOUR41teOhfhZAmXrMxSvq8/PqqdVcp8Fr@BoVecRgmjc4T/hOgNeHgjeZ3CdnqGD3tB59vw4dHGH8vwMvJ4zUCzCf1Bgoq//AP/m/7v@Hz9jSZZoNJOJ88vNBF1J/Esmzy/PL/17PZlI@C@JTfhDD3jHJOeXdXRSpHNwNRLJZvLykvvBPZHc5ADrkM1mndLO4wHzjoVZUrb8lviHfULW/nUcrzJ9vknk@HiaySSr7cAIOy556he0Ep@s0oe21tsNtfmnPyJD@1tJipTPVavqBuMvWk6rVnPBW7FUrZaCl/VEonz9qme21AKI1blcMlmtwstWADYDryHYEoANXvIA1XD1js8Fz/f2yQQ9cIl8DL/9wNlCIkMfsMBvIcXFinjnTsL/xvLWdvLOHa2cubgIfcZj8FIXvFqtrum0WuifvbgQWyLt2Sjn4T1TurhQM@WUGk/aTuIJfkQLskpIKvtYq1OuZWC@Wq6Y/IeRtAFYfnOzkKvXCzlwF0q4enz9ImowcT0eOw@G7GKSs8b4uiJWueIGvdvFi51fxqjaWS6fTABzTYIIdBnDP@6tlsvcP8lyhUQpVfb/amugf4Iowv9wtiObym0UN@6CdId/06UX8uTquVFTL2vnRgVnjS@rHf8Tpnj027hzJ1sGspYy1WOh1bq/fbTdatVEUURxBm7oSdxdwC@njZ14g6o8X242sITN43i8Ur1LzUMt5Rm0Az@eFIdhgpXKRAjB7KFdByi9wLWCNbYmaPTEm1DmlFwDT5DaMWv8deFiXdZmfbxYH@f/mMmGdLEh4@F073TCSDa//NDwldLiFfoY4SXEnj7a3tk9SmubEotpD7Z30trhs3sxFV/z83cKzuL7we72/f1nkODpo93tw91P9j7bffYU/F12Nr8CPu/f58@oa8n7GXsuvHLe6IahGxPDaJ1NJmev2SvTbJlQf8MJFMLuO8w1WoD7WJ@Xowq/junqr17pzpgu9u4H33r3g//u3Q@/8@6H33r3w@/99MvvfQt@P4bfd/jzO/@unMf7T7/8F7/77nd@CJ7/CX5/BL@f/PTL3/w6/9H7H8Pvv0T8/tj/ReLxnwCwfuWnX373Rz/98le/D79/5f@@f/33az9Z/vveN1f/MN13f/fmON/59/D7PQ4riPud3@F@@LwW/3d4vF/9/rvf@A/8/0/9P3T@8N1v/DHe/Jd//v0//S/vvvEfNa30p//23Te/@@6b33j3zW@/@@Y/1d795r9VM9Hb77773h/81R/@3l/94f9I/z@m@@@9z/@77//zv/hf/uJ/@4s/9H8/gd9/ANdP/uI/Qt/42z/4Af5/9w/@9o9@gP//07/@2z/49b/9lX9Djt/ijv/7X/07fv/rX/vPf/Pb3/6rn3z9b379J3/zW3/wV//7r/6fv/mf//q///2//mffQM/f@slf/dGv/OU3vvWX3/yXf/mNL1fcv3Xj/cv38P/yH8Hn/fF8HzjvU64P9fny58Ln70ONeS7QTqB1//K73/wlaOC/wdi7b/0Yz0nAb8X/jzWV4vyYv/1/wKFdLzOGZMAFv19/963vIIn@ByAR/If0@nb4shDCX749fwGy/vaSRL/80y//5Y/oLWZU6rQQgcN1SSulNkCl2SiX/SHbX6OAJL@0CC0E4Of0beRQC2HfRt727gdff/ejf/ruB7/17ge/ggOmlCunt9OSeutkm5R/j3gYsfA@8TDi55h/iqaRpNTn8MY@9wM///xzoXWh4IGcuxfg@zl58YvxIDyw4wcFYeiPJ3jYBYu6fWfGd677vmHOhAXmmiJBYyOQgvJZNk35CE0ZX6xAf4g03SDnFO/ki8FTAW/z/7lzKrAUxuEXfjgscJLDT@dnwZ1CHrJJTcMlEhLLGBeFNrgPLXlSvrkywxJMp6kp6LvggBxSEHQvxWq1WgoT1jg@8MpRq5cYoZJK1aDcmJqnSbdKCGJ6j6BAylrqgLU2alOeMIXw6gE5UgJ6HYiqJqZKtfuQYW16nyEsBE5gX76s1Uu1aR3BveX0SE1T9wgnBFZLTetv4b1GMCGdELv/FlAp1VKpegkzxELy6km3eCXlqXBU9hRL@XUAT9y5vnWXsY9FtSS2uHSIBOOx8Z6ax8aIEB3Cj1MbfnHoP3DSb4MIvkZZ@bkwHr5FgugWl00xAsCVJFmWGfxwLXmL3YXgKQeVomzhkeIQUtQiqAWEHgynfVJCiuo3RS@Qf6y28cEXAsPCrK@vC7G6mBX3ZSKdojDnpELb@HFnGyoeFSYWyiJ6G3SmIcAF0lcp//U4rhbFGQfMPk7x3927G@xjKCY9534Ck1JZO2fHOJTNVErUAH7dTgkvQAMRoJ0SoAtBntZIyUkJ6TRjci2GYWx/f99Hgjxe1IQUNHMtq@I7rpFMJpMYpJDltJxO@0@ZnuQh@w6ZQv2nvI7EpY/QMk3LVUFRqjL0YlGtRgUFGD3fvn0LtUJbhSp7oJsyf9eQlitRIHhwewTD4Sw4@6LlygLXy5layDGWoMlPuJIsKbAE20gKfIM5RyK4EnGtVIpTPKC@nNgINpEVVGoOOPEZqyOiwcWVxVI@GQTu7LOd/cePd58cjZtNJhj0UV2jNXbsjuG6CQzbfnKfHy7QyoVkrNFA0EcVDRmMsFvJEPvbu3@wd1hhvNB@FSQIsSotFvrFLKtCbDx@vhnzN9GI@MEoWzzEe2VetoRWzkLSWF2IdQzUKHAVuEqbJ6rCY7d/z56Cyp8WxbRaQDUuSdO9TPiaPWFozpDbPoA@hUcO5M1NooBQP5doRh6dUFsFoV73t58xVagf7h5BgqN9pmoZWah/zqYyZihdCvVhbWhYfW@wjvu4xOOMGCnTeiOTxj8tm4W7miuk1XyxubY2PJcwz2OqtnPckHcJr@cSFuMjuJjwkcA@Ai@4IA/cZcf8LY57@1V/nxkaDkrwzWaimodulhSOoaI5OGEcvarQuhfXN4TY2hdfeKxeB1Va2nsgxIBbDFiw1Uoyu/JApmruThyDQvuMdc3PTPwSmNw13fFQn0HXAWrELi8vewBp7wHT6hq98hRdvF92yKcN7supLsSsSqX2Vs0VBe2kUnmb1TQBPIQNBfdyrUEDoMXxDYX/VV3IJJstKcCpVFGERzabFXBKWBAqhsBo38PbTK0m8TaYzam07QGnBhR9WtPCy487/XgeN5vhcTEEAljfc1gmCCvyMP@tINAbEA03etGnTKt@58zcuZPF@YpsLhNOTFCJ2SXUzXo2l0WKC///deWiNZfNcT2bUTeVMTh1cOY2FR2cbXDmN5U2OE1wljcVE5yTelbNbCqTusCETW5EkKGNgproGVO0Wcr9xLprDHsyHpipiZSBJm76Rnnrfro6njyy9W4ND7LjKZFE8lzo187oeKNg1Poy2kNwLH0odGtdu0NfKBa6ctvuzmTXmw3xjMnQdmpxkPziQYCJ35HGY5w1A0QPnNnaymZzlQZrymN7vCVo@WKqoWZgzMCfWkpr6TVjq1isdOXO0NCdrXwlX0p38fiKv@K0lc9U@vLnjx899LzxgUFnWrZyZUiAxoTQ7MdWqZLPNxsNUUw1KJsmfjiVcyRpbQ26saF3JXj2bMtzJa3UhMRd06nV4vGtrKpJaiWbKQmXIYUEoC0WsC5gyhQWLI30Pff7fMWyLWAvlbSeNs@JCJVer3e5cZ6avwj6ucTfgDyXkp5un4evVSkSr8ImacmcB4KP3gPCn/srbRVRy5fEaqM6fy8WxGrzUrg7MrqmjidZjjPn11MVgA1zqDHI6JgJlxXHtr1K2@jZjjGPmFULQUSO0PUIOfEyzO44gzmeX8@ugJGAhpxy0Ji5Vcc67d5sqOVccxcYSKO5Gdh7xEYce/FC1@t1qLDzXFHL5XN5LVso5IsaDBTlXCFfgr6RKWTymgYAcuVSuXjJEjCa6bpUr2W1rKBpkpaVsqqkZvH/FoeG/@8fX4N/De@QKqsJR2g04QmMQDBqWuwRHr72bHZk4@c3@uye0VkRY2eg0z7XHcd23b9HnHu6dcKD7pvcUmEY9FDHbxC5I9MbrIjxbDxCewuG848GYXfUBgSJTVCEe3Bzhra9LEKRPXu6opSPQ9vAQAxuHBiiH@x98vAo8jza3d55KBTYvf0n96888n6kPHu0@@AofC3y0CBpPgTxtd1Hj66@@o/c/rOD3sR28Cc82H@Wm99CLzxGKeTgWowUehMQ/4avJKPhfPwayxcDhyrg5vs7oGfe8Z35wtyZQedzfkbUdMPN4Py4cEU4Cg6O6gw5WNtgHW5WAxVfMnnli8VqsSwIY2bZZ6yYYV17ONTxg8q9NfAc6HgIzkDZcEjfA8esz2xn2D0zu8aa8BjP25VV/HgtIiE8BCCjSYfsy4BcgAYUu/ipY1wAag8nBpvgZ8ZXeMIDvdDpmP0BDGJndhBBaOs6g9@HXpDeiF7ezR4ez4P8roUMr0cXYoIoPtQ9/W6sVO1U65lK5c4d9akjlrOi2zd2p9Ba2TPoPbozS5fyoieLD5jcivXNRtVtjqHGhgX1JF/J2eO6XgexvgFCMIyLWzkNKFsvZfJ//ds//rs/@fWy1q@px/HjzE4m2NvFUDZkJP75IqJMyoJWLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLg55VLIOonVFLaqGUL6vpUq6chaZXhtB8uegLmEogUSobFQBrdfC7qpukb8gDUCz42h97k9CTLKaH7xMmGpBGFFC18@hs8YZZg0GKqRmWLTKAqLMOiz14sJN58EAU7@EL7nnYyYhiF1/ypUymeE8UDQrZKaF0Ito8TQktVIkef8lk7u2I4oQDQOPOojjAl90CTk6JookvO9sPHmA@PXzRMD1EO@Eh/GUYvBQhmoUvIPcSgNchNIi2zfPJEaK7@IJZYsgDHrIDYaL4SYAOhhzwaBzAw6Ck29uiuMdftrcxZIeKneeIfoov23SJogMv0AtEsQ@OvgP9TxTb4MS@IIodcHVmOvjhN2zR/q/l6aI44@RBAonilGLrnRNRbAX@mM1nPjZ5pG6FXlRe6rv0UsY/UdQCpDFaNnzJimIufMlB2R4@/EwfeF2jz6@Zw58dKOnDh1ndnE52H7Q/@aTd77ed2fbuJwcYtLPzEOSE2cRp99t@wnYLLhtS7TzU9JPR7OoFpd5rtSr6cGnQp61WTreuBLVmLQMxhFSvATP/6mNGo9YOBO08bN3Vl63DEsAWsoERPNt43RvB857e5kHBRUH0nLbbYhWbP4rd9GV56In0kff0SO84dhXfp7U1xuKJeHrWKGSaVQpgIxCwM9VL@qR8Au86TqYkz2eNaS3TrE1rRY3v4eklxOOpljfF9NpoSy3nK2v6lqrlUtMKWjawe3EWl9QtllDvbLxhiSfJLQ0kbPF4a0sSG2pzS1NLlULxxcZEFJMVvG9lixWImIkDQ8FbslFsbhXzkSTFYkpXtEqxmKxeAj08GNfbOMnRSiTODP0kmUR0UeWGIvAP2s@onGa1l5impzWOF5slq9OaWuUmL1nmGqwu2leedDzb4RD7AG66lang4nVCVMslEfJXlEQyibowKbuKMN8o@PyrRydHR58LyBDr/lTAU/456Kr/@snDHXlvP3hDu8jyA1RvbEfeQXa1EMLN9gZeRyDgyw9hIAVdJ/DD82OOPZR3px1jjDpSEBBYu5R9G4Xy0cMFOIcD@4znjMfvq2ToyuoYDM1Gm12m1@rg0rssQVgxPXlGQ3irXq@1aiM6oQ5FDFJ9ysim8hzMnstxD40CUPJzPFPlB7RqmctquzaNTQFOq8Yk9eXI7r7UUp1qF61F36vdw8TVFjzbVaNmOI7tiDGx2tuyaoxNLFfvGU8NB81d7O2vg0CBB60SPWYk19nxLsbeQTXgUqo7zJpj9mQySoBo3k4uekVekTSJrwZFPqeTf7i34bLaq7HEi2T1Nbw66yzRle8lt3LVbuIeayXBJ/Oy97LHNFbIVekzrgmEBJ2IaINl1pO1@qcgA3HAJ5UKIOLX8QnAxJwArNmlAD05Ni@rndqQJSQ2ZUkiT67arzUw9QXeNiVRbEpS46Ip1CXpuVCHflqdxfSaO2nTJwZYpq1qmUJ1Cn5qMVcdQMXqL6ZVpzaeOEZ1CK/@vBg/4KhXgZxANQDz5iLx7pe@ntyU8jXuVyVQF0MQO1pyqzatWmi0DJpELVuDgFQjl0mDZgy3YhqGea2QVgvpbDqXloroC2N8Op8GT9BwQK5IDBMiY2I6M83Ialo11HQi89LsvkymTxIguBDJWDLt2bvWZMTAByoJWyW9wlNnyZS2MWRQCzbTNyVqpsApqlgwoPmAjc30AEEdGPqQUiSTEstuJIbrCYyzfjQZ7zaalcrudPxVCEpIr7cKqWIm9SaZrCbWkjXXeC3Uq0IduQqVerwGbdafMmTuZNSAOgaXWtQqjUYbi1jMpLOZLJTObF30N8W62Exn1goqVNElI/GIcY4RnUVDIWfuN26h5D00oOrUslYVZJrSypY0qazkN/IZPq3GUwpjn60hJVniWAwO8ybi8aIWjyfjVZzQXxP9GVzgZcTH4sBU43fULRHkL7EiljWMMGeJdF4zE2AHEtilgLMKLFcWYufC5fnlJqjFCm17BOGRrZFLkut3hViFMRADj33zQcoaYx@6mzK1WX/Bn8e4ZRzgCmRdFMRQ2uVkmKiKsc/waPoWiwNiujNqaFq22dCKMJABcwyigkJexTWMGO5Jl@tAYfcc8NtM1fFU16dsNtNTUjCpfoexfmpdoDLHrq5Tbte2@wfbwR6u7R2cpz0GWVusxsXYeTwWv4Q/IXaXjpJp/CgZi0UOk/F5@l@I343F43GcEAdCvY0Rj2A758H0VgU/dpXQK5wjNJrJt0/M4XkpK/EJCmBRl5exdYVqJjjM8@lLDRpFzLIDD9CJcCIIBqt8HiebY8rLsfuFVso@3tu37jsPDMbP9pRyLbEeYxlVwiMy1YrvmxdbaycqtImsmD1Jx9jdGG0SF8slTdS4RzXGTqS4WuHngcaH5RfFF6UXj5/tP9t/IMSO1y7WbFxXYOGet7fWV74KEePZXJyx41psWstV/R1v9bqkbmposavIKsDue2pBylzUebOuU0BBg5B3v/T93HSzBO9aRoV3TcuntHpd3dBYMjZ@9@Xvo/GV893Pth@xOM5G/92f/Egr/t2f/GvaRRa/pBlqLVuMQUx0qoVi7Px8fH5@CRcPy8eaMY5UrpgEN18tUWN1RdWylmVVWUXR9Y1iKqfdtaqKH1ctqsmYK8X8dZ9iPuZe@EFapgRBwcIMeYkFrJLY7oGZ19S7m1tQnK1sTquuYbtRwyOILPzbNNxyTIiVHr@8YAxeOvVuv29q5FIUVnkrsc230iZ7i6sib6U19rJWx1V1FQ8uBqsGG3ikC1fO4vWUshFnoAexeuOyetlM0bIDqI4vDGPDOr7S6o/X8DzCoteGBX/Ghkt/mCjwcOE1eDM2XrliYiOpKN1uaOJr02D5OjSLDQVw2wiWDvifJB0n3/3Sb2pa4e/@5NcuWhetzzXQHMvlgqrFfvazzYk1cY1u/WeQ8AazGoH2R@suaP8CHaHWyLgdRdNPFTrkDiisEwvFZB4/0CFRa0Qhw@xbRpd0SOEUBSOqyRa37NZNULQNPHWfJjGbLCklq4IQiqMkRjv9TppgsA00tAddWzgXPsIgGH1ZDbiu8NEcFHiMYLy1Oy13OHHGdHojQenUZprdgSSQw0doNG@NrAX4rFsCdqdsXE/KUXaJaiREsZHhumiCD0Yd4SNI4hshHc7YWEfDFhjTtGCskDEK4UkB3Qbk3YS8hzxBi3wTVHoeIc04djyRBaK28BFID0QFE4QKZm5ChCrwpY@AAFCGhA/YbLJNlk2yczOVqs7t@13iDna0V6gHh@oFTIbQumjEIUhcxXjgBSI@fvYO24VfwyDPRTwDIBwGXwWvgZKAyekNpTSyevHeoAAWWZhKUNHYnTtzrGo1s5tkVCKEf2KOcaKL6sFajisACxSsj7sVMc3QcmI18A2bHVA8RehCq5O4ycRqJCkT8fVSEOD/vRsttsgrVUUBVSyAX1@8V3SAZJAYyc7rsMM2a0zVikkWIt8B3DuEFJ1tDrXG4@nHsvZ5EHgJGP4sFnxUAljUUXTy0G@3V60qMBg1J2jRH21rcWbgW0Pg1rOQ1e15QeowFRTFHFLsnumARkPL84HhvkRWTWKyuaFDwoP2pWs53NGt5ZP4oFQYm8FTRwN0fj5rZDinY0OFumPbIot1ZFEHt95DiwAe5Rv74mhPrDP8AoxfN5Q4ipFLhr6w5SPGZIGPPp1LaXF9vO2A2hvQJs2Mvsw6oy7TyixBDY2MklkhuCQlIoTbIB4jjdtDYwQoHRoGnaZyK4rSB@lq0ibLbI9NaFeDByaMN5ar@F8pVs7ME1M5Qgv2kt3DQ1fczkUMBTLsfnwp3reCNrTtEzY0Tww@J5xYsBLiMlAQQMZNA2XnPyBsBfd4aNk0y0BwmseCXxEeRe4spSNp1xKz5PVnVl1LtLBGL2jwMR38AvGpbkXoS9eF4OvE7swN7AyRtRx4l0OWa/gWRmpxtB0Qms4RfItJNTLWI@NawzgBGmpgaQidwtgxThlqtwKOMcA0O4HNDuzFUNqPaACgvgc9Cw0Qek4FLc0AJk430YGu5zN4i33MspqAEbkZKN9kE8DAqq8tQocwSIrlcL0uVIxME@zIV6B3jroQhjYO/OaH6YPWjW4yDjlv3mzNB4eDDuVVY7xbBC/5yAv2DmzPVPQ1CCwAhkswWUuIKQCbEpMiBx2mv5qct3aBeEmFXYeUZgjBJzVAIVEh@EQ5i3yqRYCAe7rL7Xn75gnPzs5kspk5cUzZcPHzJS5@d10Z900QqW3FM0Zj/0ORJn4g2Ic7d0n8q0XyeDDemqLsWivfmfGnIPTcmr9TJhHvuXEcHE/x6xz9EdnXQsNWLjWoByZ92aeT8Dfu8PanNdPnQfurYPuTSvFLBMIYgpmmZ@lOGoCl252TdO@sW/UDTqlDAnCoRSPwREu2TvAycgOXOe6FMWwP@WgY1B6e0MIrQBL5HO48a17CIOYsePXfx@YUElnGGdt2HH2WoPAkxsYGnJiR2MNmMOxTCDhhmGHn3KyqOW3MmgvJp2FyGNQCjYk5aDxLOL8ZKLexi@FTHj6F8CkPn84zDbJtTJtcJEOvSywOtnq0uRjERDCzIM4lt0c7DyHIIH0zlYPAmLMFv0v4dWqUOqA3f4N6rAUNA9rEGAhuJJTGi@PGcdNyjbONZkrpQ2MXiRBQ4wC60SSannVDN1J/eDoc2@6Cl4WmNmFU8vFGr87Abw28rWAZwwqihsHpZaJ1xP7I37DABQK/wAAB5TAIRNFg20uYyWpo05kCoeE0xDmNOWINH5kmSV9@kO8H4hInPSdsFFAzAgj9wyIBmhDCgp7DP1YVcIfnjg1xgrgSfV9nhFa64s04UPJKV@G8pkqVFMFKkgI0gewortauFiUIh6poXAmKFPPSr/8o@msfjH4P@sVy7KnB8gGjKkS7Cm4LBBHC7y5EVVavReoVMFA29KHhwMi1y@VTf7SGbDaUQM3g@WAR3DP8AnciUvmdJK8fOnooWmIlbAqzWg2KOKvxbsn7RUBSTvAwmesnmwUNwU/PGQjAyCxNZvjJptFk01qNMw42XZHsLILklJCc8iQ89nQFkk0/GWhPe8HwgtXTBOkU9y2KAE/lwyiIQWOR4We4cfn7FVoQxMVSP885z6FW4LchFLGxnXWaS3NvRJCOMK0rALAhXgPQ5d@9rAhXGZ4qhW8hj@KkDHgUf/ObAecV0MCIBVe5ld1E2MhIBwaBX0zROAB9V0w1BFGliWD8y/CfmA48g5963TOzGFNd9Mykr/z9o3g2kbKRDhqRPtRMDhkyajLPLN88ZVTmiOEnogc2SHXtM5sllgjb4K9M/KRKe2i3lZGO21jwa3j@F@LHs2SgP@AiCrs7tj3ds3O5CleaTGp2y/LnOoPZt2z8iEbE0jbIel3bcK24B5XasfuW6RpphkYQTwxf7TD8DwUIUTnZd9quIPhTmFyNRdC8XaGo22rh93lbrQRu9EtWwv3LtO8Pm2c8LqD@C65IemBPPtD9ccJuvzI6XvJ2mGg23k92ZHZOEvtjPxCnW7cZ8LAOyP8QOgAJhrn2XHMkk9QoSre9BH1JYmCP7D5IfRNXFjD1FfB7c9iIkD4eEy5ppqNKW4l8PIB6SaKT1pN@0k8/OCn7VEvoyTC9tghggRhp5lylMVLWWZJda2V2PFmQ3@GH43sYxffwZnxJC7@KM1fNazzww7LOJuYQIOIcjeztaGDRgW91r6GzgErojXIVT/DeKHZpm1gXMd2GqNt@dLkH7SMdvrnwFiL@2Sr631yBQfLd960@HT9afjgDfjPC7Y8J@u6RG6yGJiD6XhJ5z/XswqZ9/z3zgrj4ybkHKEKAGEuMy0JrutAxx6B2u@F0cQD4ljaPO7OutXvarlXjgUtwck7T7ERbXUX3W11jqM@MbsKPmY7ADUp8AAob8av3KzgyOmJ6Ntf1EjB2JcNQGMaR6DxSZUWT0dOnyeTqZsWjmGHroZlywnBvNf0w/Bprxim@Gp@tBj0gHo/hdOypidOf49l4xg22D/nXb3w@yscfXpNoX@F2ggAd@OippufZJm9inweJsEjvMSKEceXFIqM95QAi2gy6XocfRqLbSwqVG0lUC2pZWPxUyfIaN2@q8UirCNokX2Z6vyZ5W6N77zYXaWoc2JyF7XzYEHINMm7g6HQSUYjc58Yas61rPAH9aJ7OWjGqtJYw1DAlcTrPJHWb5IukgJrxHjxxwukzeCLAvuG1eIMKyoZzWv535BiFjPRxRGrxfUBIBygRKnKS@2hEYgmBG6KfX4Z5dlbm2bmWZ2chz7AHLGYZiSR0FrL0awGr56YqGBo9bwV3xiDUneFxE9uGy7J1B2crzuNmvGKmWfw0XgGGHDfild0EMOV4N165Tw43Xjkkx0m88ik45n0rfhGvBN0CIzjwSo676O@zcHzvxCs7ieSl4OknhhvkK8crYZ1CnC3@ShQBUmC5QWrEJTbL9ovpOQYMbCRUphm2GDeN6hPNw6Tpl4F//vEh@iwJBuIc5wZFZimmLgwakRGD5wPDRmD2fklPrvij@e7@A9oAFUbBbFKg40XTEHgQw2PxRWbEEcNQWtGAJyCIfLOyHCMWGcneEx0/d2ihVMmL@RP1ZJIHugkKb0Dk5jwT@uKUnz6or0UQvALfD09MvArPa@gE2RFGuCabXIIWEvVl/IZCYV0v4uLXfrSGaK57MRJgKwVReC0R2AhPBxmOFucws7E9XmwkFIqb7c1oGpqU450SW@@VZMQV/J65Ipi8/ZIhY4h2/uRNxYmkQ9QWWBAGNjJN3svCcYF4MQbNeV1EUuWdD1CI8Bzo4UbnhL7mdd93UjzObtI0VqwahoK0PEviXItsEhLLaLBqons891B53UUzVh@mvgYppzjXkkAAkZRhLpy/2h8gv9tcfg8E6oAIVzJYJlgvH0qvi9c3jrJXMB/Os71egRiYZveTS4WjMIc5yUE7iEjmN7W1ayI@bvngQj7PNIR@RdoPyBbqBLfQ7apuwWGhlOCcLnqeaOB5oq0m1HWJZHgqB0KLjDn5cHjBQ0znRbsZV17wZVWMITS/rQ8/uIKdxQqOVh7CowI4V0jOe7kzsWiXy7xvA9vmPshS1QrjjJyWS8NqnnsCu6el23DZFjz2Wwf39588@hoMusViMemP0bM5fthrca41HMc5ZNpNHY4HS9QWLY2f3MHFbpyOdwe2460dW@I1XsKZNQgDOuQSND@/jyd9Xhbh51f6LqTjcSMU9WGdzLuBvsCVUNTRccg2fbp6QBDDS2zoPpBAvAV6p0lbS9LHZVotSx8ZrRYNX60Wbl5qtfxRDKsmWBFP/iy2pkxch75Dy7@MdCYIZJmB3d9nzx9uH7Gjh7vswbOdT9nX9p@x59tPjvBQ/tNn9x7t7TD47T453GXCwjZL/IocKpRA1/tGx8BPgzItk8kxgrxjj2ec7yR2ktz/UB@xh3bHwGWqTVcf3R3wF9kyvDpPtQvq6AznME36auDI9HC/BX3mDtRYFG66dEAQN/8ziNsGnXaEOu/I7po9E@IKqPuOTcMNzpSxofn/FHetW20sy/k38xRtCRsNjG7YYGwhbAHC1gkGHy729gKsLaQRzN5C0tYIkGyz10l@5AWS/3mEvEreIb/yFEl9Vd0zPUJgfJy1jtcympnurq6urq6@1YV6kOStMTf2ZJGEiHasOsSRKqGBdU3FG5QfdzcEpiH6VyAxckgIvFZOacJF/36YggfVvXf7Cv4dNnZ3NmsHtd2dfbW1u0ev7z/Vdt4QPWv7B3u19UMkccZ3u5u1rdpGhT8IAoWcguOF3y7D4b0o5JCdqdL8HTffuT51f/SWPPXGCl5dN9hUMlRzl11In6DRCb74rbmScxli@QLzTL4qUJnZyt6bDzTnK/8P3HCaq2DWP0gdhhxlcbagVrk2GixrNN5KjvGkmMkWXb6PuBgrBFrxS@yQIcPPnjLAWYmnFfgqtQEdFZx9i98GHssGNFX0iGADlFFYKSsOkDQ3560yyDWqrdnpwcWm1CZKhPoFRV8bVZOSwxTTujIACgOHWhfnQcVS9IH4nj4s6mqHA8mgnkYfJIN6Jh@wFK1Bd0Qt6RyXw91LiGe1LB9@u@hv8bWweh59WG/wLnZF4yT9xl3aUFGAOXix6HAYLDnl4VCdjbAZBFwk5PwIEdXpyMDwJTghyUS5SmTdNsqZImHTxlWDVnuTmL9IJW6AnlCjPQxVpuzm1AGUg/xuIAHIzjqNrqhAxao7zHtqBQ6Dymt6@RAF7mKTkX6PGRBBA5N4ROU29arQf2g5Krl@q8aG1pHk4JlGBe17CKzfQuDvAUOAsomdTpNnKrZeBZheW7NyJuwRR@Lc9k87P7Fz67LpJwpora3Mb8GXL64mspfYJxk9RcaOuuiLP6BlJV9ltnsDGuMsVjnUEaRg87zXHwbSh5lkC/jGiac5yo2JjWr71RBX1wY6TNbY7XWtSk@Ji@@o9ZSY8iG1MsfL3XkkvuIYuMT5NAmL3h3QaZz2rnzr7szDJdK1j@MXWgjzXTkOP8dDxkTWn04sO/5UCJ25Ul7bXD/O/vmrh/iZIhYkfK1ROsR/YkzURcOD7/lYYXGAdZceaSbuWXh5itJaB09LS4xyA4z2gecB7ete10tRmqgb3/4Oo5rJ7/zx27eylMpCMumYx@F5JpZunjoyVXpc5kRpFRBLdhKyJOsz5ovHMCN5/RqGNOgFeMDpQo5g3z4RVUyLENO608s2SRYd3FV3dwTfVWusURFHxoaBjN0f@c@Z9fLCmpuPFUqURc6MEdGegVx0XUstheerW@A27wdH8vvh4FbuxU6mhx@CtnkvtB/CLbtwNyyZlixYDwf75z1gZXL7u8BS2727AcskeRtaxOkRc3qz6Uib9v4af73Vdzz2CAzmXpygRECt2i67fEVtPFpnpIBrg4kXRPsHm9W9PZWS/QmVJbmHLUNLi0HAfqTex9q2QZeFXS5aNNluqGXxZL4kNNrMv/sG81Ti3SEq9BrE0/SIhEUcpqYdjETq6ZmFlxCsfc8C0VAuid1XI4PCIw34hvaAhGzcaVYDnanNTMvkE4S2ErimmydrY1uHnzWsZe5GyNTB2AZk6wQ1zmBZMr3/Psr6@KWpRxZY8CGEBrdoJU3zDe0T9qniPmXM5ZI9eE@3mC6Fkr0ssNOGdlD8KiRX2D/PUMxIsgiXtbAl1vXiWKMm6@NZs8xhhURMAw1oeupE0WimBCPi@cuq3aFuPOllklMQLTIRRPO1zRVU/ORGT2FMjWieLEcLcnuszTI2RwbLE5zOatiluzM9hi708qR4mKyKpO29VWX/f6qSWSJRk6H51MaYRIK8vLT09HuwJ1thimd/FrbMIZPyc3jRp/19DDIch3y8T5xb2/FMeswA95BOVOvNgJkoSEudKXNKou08Gdn4ES5yLkTIwL874pJO1uqq0QRu06HLjGRD5yy32mAN4aihMmpuUf/m/uogkL9b36Mfr08GGzJBdfAGWvnveoPQj63yLGcu1ieYvya/@YNBl7OJPdMFoGTYjOleYzu2thOFV2kVEvm@zW5JW1snidqtZ84auBI@XswhFDFO90qTx3vZYslu6lZtu6rm2e9jO3EWmRqkXEv2PAq69yHAMpjPJTB9sA3f4/Al/SccPAOSyMTWfBmmjftd3JgitGo@4vg@Wi1Uy9biZO@3w2ajCx8gXupxqFLeEyrIp7DV3S132sl6oZQoT8iF/W6GSnmpbC7FRekbDnQBKQlCehPfrQkLlhpGUxLmNWc96EfhYssfyekZa0428sWVwvILh1vX9YbexdGLE2@@WU4pmnwb3YvwcnDd@v2sd37VVh3V/@101Bx/@UOppWfqKdW1@ESc7xaXy3n2d/qc/q6oF@zZaFYj@IodCSM0bk5ihio1p@J9eOmRksghvGl@CQuJCS5V8xeGC2FiNyxfHC2flLvlQuniqHtSgpHfcKE8XCguZPDhCc2iJGPkZv5oeII51T519btXCi4uOUqlNg1RbBpCX941BkFvu7LzJnEahwUAjsC0rjcfqEsY4hlos8H2JNf1rzP6mMxT4FgHCyRnhq2CirCN5/NkHMe0AsKMesWj1Ww44r9j15kp5C77wx6nGO@GYC31LfjmzBgzpgKfKFCWo8D4QIR9AcGJ82RwMSRfx6JFnS3Kcq0I20nXAnGEkiwOU8epFGwKgai25To6ccKc32ieAwnE3f7GxdTqKkfhJlYLc3yKB1WOxoANJgoneMQFCP30@bYBVfDKPWSzD4eaj/ciHuQLn1EN2U6GFeQdXikiBerf6ivbN3H5VSKAEH5G1lw5fcSpV160kBTbQT5cgIuz5MYf1wwwq5ROmUFjAVvqK8fAWVOcaYRqNZno@8w1yCm0on@6Bdkiv91qRpTflexMEr6n1m8haMldyklr@OnExTJWsawpZjJbpJj5LjVw0kXbo3c@Daux2vA7HUJaaDETkwOPbN@r61@I6g@PUOdJhLykZ2@lZxPpOUkXpOJcOZrg40wv7Uyp9Nc4341Kxdm8W3WVFS9ectTTzRwtSeK8pfvyhrlhrx7EmdeirhSujBJWEwlZK@XzlN6XlEeJMhGDR@lHkq75e1H3fIRlIu/rZP34dXQH@aw8q3VNJrg01w06rxwdslmngM1SRE2lpDhHFlRmUJW1DaYWJ7SCwzk/D9u1cgxloWgkDo@Z1Nrq61ROLzJeZSbRECvGWwNryhixqMR1LjDhRmywSPVw8iMLBMMEoykzctdM4bEuPLbAItcjU61YQd4a4NS0ySFehl3kN/wxgz2JnMmXnp44I5iPpPFi3ZwkEAvdR6npZEpKE5iLyEfdqHtmkbju8STE6UJixzoFjur0xQa7jWPwR5GcsAWFkRS36B6laErHGYqGfe/qQiTeOP@bn3feNGiN3e/4I1XBNqPBVlhOwsB96IfDEM6g2KdNeNnvd3DryAu@azah1n5FFpdw3RJDtGb2nFODZo/k9/CkDdKpUE7tAvI1FETihPDy7AzGZLCA7V1DtOLEJRjmnEp3LAcaNGaeLoqZua/gfIMFcCc4s5GQnpPRA0qH/UbTzzm0Rgtp9eNIU9uBjsjJ5@mwG4G7MZrSXjrOXy@D5u8bb3Cf@7xYeFq0SHalr4MLuafPYgMrIpJJWISrwKXiM8ex7oabcjecBUBPbWOi/0C86V/53a7vVGjG4IwhLVpDf3Dlt3KOs@dHl8CAC1bGzSTssHuXg6Yc7tCiq0HMCCvh0JPrMOIw/GJ@luviJt@VeQ4ureLbZurqq6AFAhqLk3YPt8N8YQE3AUIPFLrwh0SUeVclUeK7Z40Lr10ucBBF1ICfE@tuIiJDtzcMmtQzfJLldAiUXIPElXVbE5hQfc1OA8bBuWkIwDwmpoBBwFwl3YeDoy/NfwgHpRtm7tgbpmfyJP16PFZouPuDgKRvTGDuFS5m4U4dfPC2tq/2d7cOPlb2qoqe3@/tfqhtVjfV@ie@48ZFOfvfVW93t0m6RLfpcmu@Sx9SlX0qmeIEp7LzSVV/eb9X3d9Xu3uq9u79do2gEfi9ys5BrbrvqdrOxvbhJt@@EwS1s3ugtmvvageU7WDX41pNMScup3a31Lvq3sZbeq2s17ZrB5@4xq3awQ4qw61@Rb2v7B3UNg63K3vq/eHe@939qkLDnM3a/sZ2pfauupmj@qlOVf1Q3TlQ@28r29sTDd39uFPdU6wkYLVyvUpYVtZpC4uauJ2btb3qxgEaFD9tEPEIwW1P7b@vbtTwUP2lSs2p7H3yNND96l8PKRMlqs3Ku8obapyT@Q5VqF82DveqcJcESuwfru8f1A4OD6rqze7uJtN6v7r3obZR3S8pZ3t3nwl2uF/1FMIPctUEg6hF6fS8frhfY7rVdg5ozjh8D30Hlzr5IxGGsKxQ0U0mMNQg0Foi0u7eJ0AFHbgDPPXxbZW@74GmTK0KqACNio0DOxtVSEQ8sJupdqpvtmtvqjsbVSTvAszH2n7VpQ6r7SNDDQoZn4h1qNJDbjX6ifCSR2JWx3Cux92paluqsvmhBsx1buKA/ZrmFibbxltN8xyc8lqHKEEPZwaNC/tgpX3705UPb5S3T2Smn9FEHpM2djerNCNr31apOOGQZp2VCVdKdhrNNFEivSZc1rT808uzetBt92BjGhWTg4@L8MxDpB0XYUqOnXsCTenzFS6QTtfrHyp12uju1@uu95CSCTS@V0Ifg9@Xy9VtRHAD7Lxx8PPypdB9NUGotSf6opMV9XABgZxC/Sei@ta48F2Vz7d8XQzG@wBsjo5CuTY5x1UKiUY2dkR8lbhKPpng90CzAxfMGPC5Zh3npNCM5Ey9kP50v8UvMjlYH0g6y3FXPo9NLKMRfPFNNVIJu0TgP9ojQdDmKnOh7/9@linY1WHPnzvr9VoZ1zVlOO@Q9oFnGfc7xU/9s4ni2cnyjCxfO@uAAaHZd/MSJrp/1iRTul9yA25ZBn/qQ/5xDTbi8wGnplwVH1brQ8vMEykOjSRPadcWMK/gTsaa713ll9pH7OYKi89KE9/fRt9lbEFfEF5racI74nIn/PP2RDLQAGNfHESSQHvIyOetMkbfJMp8TRnPkek6aEHzh@bqc5/ndSIJLWQvGx27TszGg2BkY09y@M1e5d364dYWiU5g@2xl6flyyYncbv3iye8n1MOuZdnrWJ/mcVqncZI1SjZo4cMjxXLpHbM/M3A@j4zw2246jT/Cz0Okt5HUZIIgQ3NDBBvqQkUv5YMOKcUOOB45hl@njkzNAJlEU1205qIx4iV@g9ZKzANamaUz5l4b4Q9gR8PfDPGoQZqBNIuxs13iXNpdsNxLbRlVUd7csOMeZMmlDB@LG7eIBnzUxfqzsK7lN83bVi@GosqI8crdziUJiUeTWCijV9GVkf2e/YzoA2D2HkZfftH8Ro@ftIM7dnfXCIeV4T6RcSsqiXPq@DBaN/pIQz5BDA04VTM1rSqc8rsaKR57@jg5cgxijQZGBcFWoOObBFyK/IhMVskasK/nXPVVOBXOOwCnpDlWvxPnTmuOhlIy/kP0u/FKoQRW5OREqHYd1eGYLJ8iPxaGnAky/RQ9GP4/kCZT4K/SjpOgx9SynAA@iJIMVWhF21cmSnBtLhqs242YmvanTzGYG7tjzqOG6dubkdjXEAl074zNh0/s9rCdmUIAMDkONuzxG6mknTdo6/Q65eriuCfpNi/6GaXnCjNV3IKbXT7xeNnlmbsVvLjKlbMmq8JtKqpey8btlEc9bZkmtvLqcZgScK7x/5Gf5wOQaMAzl56L1uokZxX0KDNyQLtasiacVuQxiZalN3fe2s0ry0VmQvbrmy9DKAK9Bnxut5MDivSUqOcmPS7yTKwO2AseHIhjm4zJR7usO2VFzI4POI9bfBiCmCPDa0wQHYHOrvpiaCrzmBVFUEmsdRj7GYS4dXNEWp5WryPs@WQSHBphf9gVz/W@nGqZHDlx8KExtM3lc@pdY0wodx7WbGGx/Px@z4PuIiqTYwldHvFVmr3egJaODbSbcPSCsZtTH/Whg98NLwfafyHNZ8FAn0iYRT9Vg2WT7N55mhGn8YxaGAxhrdDKMX9wky58aIiKe5JRdllliHkNj66ZQ8dgtFBUmdU4ZZVowm5JmYirall9@ya5hKDaZajPFAzCaHPBOptcD@4douF33Rv8jrkfS6Buy29FnkktkHwWKJ1U67KPx@ZQmt7vhXyiQV2BE5CIEkU5SIsUVWmOfq7ZSes1pWLvmPBdyi358XoiJjXaUlRRzLi6dmK@5Sx1Jqi0qF2DRs5Ci4tLjMq0DdfNnZsx9haavLZWqeNuJFJeyiKi/NgsHfEkcjN6@oQnfchffhxi9NAX3HHrJSgQxpoV96q35RzjB52Cj4E/aNlnorSSaTX6OH7jrU@vy7xojg61279mYxj6Y9oBNPPBKM8w6pm/9M679Y1ep3EW9IIG7dPg930kEg@PY35Eh50Netchhw7ihJaVqTWOn8W/jLhhw3t0L1myXHOFQ7@fsdUUhoNx5VzcRPDJOZQA4wigzN/9SR9pUZlnS3EhJ2l/yvp4Rbd0Z9mnxWmF5UYfALSAW5vQoBAb0iEbJlnGp6VbGU7vy2DheKqyquHeobGXwPgFkYivYRIYG2RuqSXYjcDO7E6Mj1ojr8U@CAdwtORv@oh9E2b4s9dAUGWSIq@gKfBSFVcKVlG5RRnBDyEexneTe/H5Pxh7QuAn0C8@ncYt0xiBRVzbeFsKZb@ivYwSLqweGLCMZklMUiw4C7qW@SFHnRhNQk0mj@@iBmv@0KJIu9m7xZUYkRna@CDCXaZOIqc@djGpzKk5l/12YAlSGWYKdzOs/z39WR78uMSVkzMIpg0NOWMhfRepmkQlhK2dUK@1URafyt8fMYuLD@21CQKWp6mcWeGTMymzcmELlEDmV1xr9QYkjFMT1NOqHnPhsNefeyD17pQdUz2zTaN103W/qwgszFamyXK@xaQtj/E4LjmT@EwwTZJirGlGPITtKz9HbD5JxFG5jvFWro@/Q4e7aBbrTUWTStTfLRn7mBSvoNFrJppoSDHucFJair4f1anh9bsliIYp26s6S4w6REZ9LI8WqAkyRVR6OIWY@zTuE/RoEeVQb4toZ/fPnUSdVJIzLk9NUsLJJegJx@0w2iS51G9D@QJu4mSFGwmpaME58sZ8lVfMnsLJMBIEIFbFfjY@h5IT3LizJviIowO0M3VoCxUhiehpzdZwiJz@RwRjr/z6cEdrPNTH2eJJSSCNIki0q@Bc90Ey9ub0elQfMZRbpKAhPoUUUYtuyabzh7fqZ9tC@QiClOZkrelb8NAYVy0QNvTHTqqPsAaOq9IlEyMqORDqLBpoLNAu5azjy3YVq79gIBwP7QY9jGgDIZ8z@FnQJeDOe7kQURtFRq0xsria3DLaXJVdkyIxQ8k7yK@Hoix1eeNKAHzBmMqXiwQBbk0Ze1wKsOsdm/MSiOo@ooLlIoYlfWSvqLGe55R0EFVneLZk5ShMy/HChpGdCoQWFtPzxIjQmmV6lhgKTXRTcbFyPJ/enjgHLYgN7wvFqSt0ryRpGPWcEJCDNxfcWKIcFZVX0BzMic@W3ERixN@c@qJgpRYmU4k@EYZH2eJk6kohkZqodnExWTRRkujh2rUmEokUro1wJBV@7h@bptguzyOdUGuTkVhlaP1sBNemXSbt23K/hWqVjbLNGsPAsy3DzfarLiFWEk7Z73fArub4ygC@23@6tUYz1WCiYwWwXzpj7JKRDSGvWFOY6tEs7HSNp73IQYHZ0/ba6sPB1lbC7evp2CgaXfiDpUKhACY@tZ3fG91qHCUFvXwyd7592enk@9d/GXw4zbPs930OCfDS7KB96hIaFGGuNziTyBDAgbIid1YbsmKvf9lu2yEYcEOJzqNuk5zaG4LiCSiIlF4@HPABEIPUE@yvaCDa96uKRt91QxaaGoq5hqLSUAm@SpnbMyIPPrShnx3dVDEwCGajzUTzllte@4oZBJFNuLPYfbH7NVZPTr31O52epz4i@DA8BczcTBbY2rILFCQLbhjZuvcyZH@0nvKvgo5lV4wsNq8DnJmYTJwJ4xcevvH3/LPqqJ9JHX1O0bRCTV5AMxfgn9pTqbOUq53FPwCs8CGh/aDcF41@psl0msxMU70ewfETYfS06E3d@ySyuHwmpmn2/dwg6nR0c@ysgZru8lrA@LLn7uWW3JE9Im7qeFRsg4YFgaFxgs@Vh5WAqdk/TixeDdvth0lFDgMgHftDElEiofycQOQ7AB6BevgRPeFF@5@yNKy3JhyKyAIHwTpuyx0UqKOA4zxulv@4zlQqFTXbX1hQlco6PWSzqrJeUZv4sL6uNul9He9PyotLSyWRuZvuV/q4bj7eqHWCwSecC83zwSa9UloZdmPQ1kYXz@bLs15ptl5eXSuF@aPKOsz66em///lf//tf/i1f0S//gZd1fjn6HGXK5XL52ebX2Sc3JbwfbZ7MzZ4ezfZP5s5K4LL/Za/hvdow24jVR3ODUycts4D1lfVIzT6bvc/oosoEBbxoDH4n6fJSpZthPq2/hhI5imVsuulb333YUZ7SFt4EHZjcyhMSaQI6xnE89U7ThwIezTdEScIFeqBSXu5WzME93MFEGaJblbT2xMNr1isfNi2xJwXY4tKMlQ26od/FCfgVr3mleY7ToN9gWNf8m//8Ljxb743U/HFGzRfUvKfmUyn@KS6/oK/ubD6Ada5ko@1AKuVRSny1ADVDFQa80OP9A8famSC348xyyB5AMm4qOLNYwXnR7o@NZSTgWnjmzCD2ppIjEr5kQpH019nuDXXLV8pxk0qY2vBCoa53MVyZdaMS9S@WQI1QFAHimi@EIC97VCVu@tgiGU9580X3tcPRhBgwyLr3ZovHPT7QXDTb1TrPib0Uwhyx@rx8xdxYEmNoRhspUn@MAF@oyHaywJaEc@k5R7S8rVZyM8UK226fZj7RdRj7Q6ObLoX@VBYTiDa3TbjZrrZr0Yrccr2iUkF0vWJVlZrU/VaOVeTisjMM@tpcgWvHgPoa1XYjIwk9yoAEjvjsf3l7hPFBgfEUNdEtEixrrFo9NF1GQlebplMHuzm5ObKIkP@cobH9bWJsu3m2EjHsIDzASEWqfO1G0Am115UBE/usMThFdMBGmwOqDeXejM/zEG51AuNeO0I6x5BZ5Twez9SUdH/QOLtoeCq90zsYNMY1mrZo5TNs5lxqIVwwAQkMPl31tOYZhKVFukuYIlFTWHMIwQs6Yx0eTfo2FdmcoEvNUNBuVzAIEuzElPS/Jfpqgo4xV/9AJ9go3xLe0W2kFrEseaFppCGlbLMZHma3ho5jarDHTjRwUo6gGo1Mwwu60CUm2gu@@CVJ3oGPAF13SlsBalOE5ReoH7PTmd9tJCanfscxhv75kpJ5EeOZQ1GKNpJjAqUW44h3wIrWkZ@TXiBkbjLujJyZTGbmONTh3NL2PMJOviNd/HxDBVEAOg5gxpYh6rAbiLCcmKHiGBg5VWPNf4LQ7jTOCL/xdWMMVjxOZ149yrtHn4@7J/OZ4@634y8uY6JFspllsyqtL7ONxNJjhWbGvJd4NVppoXE1eNxNZjjuKrFhsUhAiOQzR5/zJ9/yhNBxGkHoj9NCkESXAZP8/fXlAT5/C810Eot82plx513T@ZlXRVfR3Mq/6EP54MovYWE2lXxMT/ucQZtAsZ3uH5dichLmVxYLzxaLz2gndOaPsgP/EvNtNrw89Ue0lAixnaWp5/hLghsShLgZhY0SfRxROyWsidiehNpISYtQPcy5HidiKyqTE56g/ERldpcKExc3ytPA5SM2/J4iljN52ReUqA5a3JfB/Bn2LlBPI4Rcm7QOEY6EloHoiPARahaQTfCVuzjUNcNlju2ccmoDvlsZCHVvPm3NFt1eN6sXa25uroRFNKxmOiuFlcLkGL01RBMjdFYvpuYeqeLaq@f/9e@7f6SH6bXF/McB/Q7Tf6SXV9LySA/09tS8XaXX0qvItnyTHudpD0yPz//rP6n82l8IDlLGq/RnbcnAWh6n17JlLvItvbZMD8XFRar3f/72N2rDrOzYEIt1tu4pRqxkKLLR6DLvUrqqoZWyLZ2LxQobZgGGaBjS3pxeoBg1Wlwp8DFdWmtVXPna85XRR9FTPCtmDVlVSE4yjD4FrYykQBkVZAWkUaFoK0t3w6htgHljNNWvj3PLIe0AftXqHFGVkerG4xAqQ7OyLaIOzEiNtJ@Xh7XCq1Sk3vEyZXRKSmYJia2dlrUrT0v/Bw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/f3km2)

Bracmat has nesting `{}` comments, which are used to comment out most of the polyglot. Pre-main code comment starts at first `{` on the first line.
Post-main code comment ends at last `}` on the last line.

Main code:

```
#}}} }put$343 {{{
```

First space fixes Perl6-Pugs, second space prevents printing `]` in Bracmat (`]` that follows last `}`).

`a aa5k x##` on line 1: `x` is for x86/Z80Golf, `k` fixes `x` in Beatnik, `#` fixes Befunge-98, second `#` is for Turtled.
`a`s were there for Poetic, now they are not needed, but deleting them breaks x86. `5` was for Delimit, now it is not needed,
I forgot to delete it.

Line 2: `##` and `a` in the first `a5` are for Z80Golf.

Answer (score 2):

## 356. [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), 15916 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11    .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{














































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hatax@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!!92[ ]?42e>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD4o6Ph/SNSoLpIigRAgN@kSJVKpepSd1WrpqTqbjfJYoEkSKIEAiyAlMiSVDEzezfnsb173tmxYzz2usez573xeSPWt7G7Ht/auxH2/bjh2J/8B5Q/Li4cF57/YO69lwAISqRUNV5HbFwcJAKJ/Hj58mXmy/fy46Gje8Of/jSGF3viWPOB5UzYxPAmrOeap4Yrs3tzdlc3vbyWFQSMtesOpiPDnngVIcZUxizdHkz1gcH6pjUx3DTzDIN1DMs5g3CNse2pPfWMXh3esozZxhk7sLtmDyCwiXNi2OZrw4WwHGP3DetidDFhXWc00u2ex8auaU8oNM/YEx1e@tPuCdM73sTVuxPTsSGowNgz29JHnZ7OKPrYNXiiIgNQ3RNKsxxSYuyx43oG5OB0Dc9z0LMMnrprOo92P/3oSnw1wz7SAamxZcyuZK@q7HPTcHtXU2jss@MHD676ZtknkmOzB9dRUnNsdzpxDiZX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7GlgAYk4Mq5QpZa4GFaE@jYnZXcoHAh6YLtSu7tci6@o21BbW5RYzRuPJnEm8/nXLCuvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZmToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12YszPHBeq3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikgAPAIhXYjI0OJyRPodKtifQOJjOPEDDMgJoSSEG8e8bnemAOdPJeDphgFvP9PSOBUA7c9Yz@vrUmqRZB8KAyOR/NjRsvzEDOBlAHDscq5dTQs1YtHm912MZaMeAx4nBTKAaoVVh2Sz4M8cFqkGsACMfGLVrXkZjBnUGVdR3KiyfyUD4fuiD2OqW5/jILKOGgTb0VaozhPvEdQauPgJq9Ayi6WcHT5jXdVx4gx/G5f3pJjBdfcK2t1l8/9P7cVYPq0V2O0JYRTV2DlUQCwLZqW5NoYVEa8KB@nHD1AJWWXwjXmFxIIuWYbkcy0G3LTEtD0RSM2VwQP/Xsir8CkwrsZwKPSgfT2M@fVcfmJbBoQwQShEbvpZnGtwzOZZVSzzmwLH6PFqXMiuybIkViqyYZ0W4l1lZg9wQdI6p5Tz8CvADaGVARYVfNscBLdo9tFNsa3usr49Ma@5DJ/BdlldZESACvipA1koAAZ7ZLP6y8CO0lq8o7MkQqD3UTwG8ZJknyI2MkCFhFSrwULa2FOKIyHJ59t4QswfSAdHyJVaE7AtAiRygAJTVSpB9PsML4g0Ny/KTDT1MRtgWM/ADzItAhxJQPwO0zCAxi/CDd@B3GjA2DbiYBoxJA2aiaeDOYhYQrwBhBajKgk@voe6dQEY8H61HxAeODmBUpDYyMRWJBBCgtlgW6qzActAQstgQ8lkG@AMuxQIDPlZSWSnHSkUG9CxnGNSNCnhhK1GBf6qAj4rAoP5VaAAq4KQCtVUAqmbzTIgQW81iOKTNQlogjZqDNDlwQ8WpBfxBOmgZKmSpQp6aVl40QsBNy0N581lqnVoBarcIYUA3DXDVoDlpgK1WgnBMWwIalrDxFuNpTggd6QC1gs0d2iEQIw/4EFyIC26tmOX0063xUO8gt@YpO31MWsBuUEAyQtIMFg@eOaQmoJIBMNgLAH0NWkAWyJGFqs3mMPtLATowH66j7A@4xOfY9ZGZIcMGZuUQK160yYQdsJskcMdlzgmszIK2CcNFV0e2hp3cICYVwDEnMoNMYGw1nFOUBYjTLGXjETfquDj0w9DRM1yXYVyQF7w08S1v2vGMV1McnBZ49YERGsAv@7pphQhQ59QnxFXhGfcgv/ky2n3XGVEPHiFfshxnvGYMAC54hoAeOmfGAvUFk9THYwuGIvA3@EgIyJzpJMSQxBPNlSMEiTBdd2gCQMoKWLjpGl2ivV90SJ0FZr@MYoVp9TtZhHIvMkZl2dgB/u1hGntqWRUYPIwuy9aVnnGqoA8fx5bHL8QhGNlgfPJBdHQQQBBzwiKEdEeTacw8DmrWc0bLReNM6yAs@tDE0cY60@dQe33gV8ZMH4GYxFAWsWGEHEGL4TWINQGCIBbrgPUcOz4JoZy5IBlAocOSkPSBNJmYIwNESgeSYI3nCGlkmYRZZw5NmaiVk0mG5JhcIZQsXCUU98hFPHhngTG0N@0i1TBv06YWBGOPh4KTa@g97idMXNZs6vBzYZAc@2KzjA6MeISoRaQuGGENoL4vznQJIg78hu2BrObJzEShFlr@wOlDYzszoewgLkHSBewuEQFJEHrN5K4sEMmxAY1OLGay7njMwB@EEGieDzIlGNedlyZ7DYHWEOSy7tR152w2hpowRxBr0nX6fWi9r43xEECwUY91513onlDJ2HqEnkMcqTteLubibdOAODZKentPfoENDCA7SAF9FPmxyS8KMB5TEYgUus0lBFsHSmERuuM5kQXAhCn6jiOjf88xPGosjnsSdn3MzDMG1DWgn/UXzGiEEg@0UpsktR5wHr97IXzMUFhZGMzKbwUfGTZ0nS60Suj0UH1Yp7usD5pLRC5A4U3vdo3xxG8nDrEz044IUYcPUIgiX8kHJntDYfMu277SaiBq2HIiAgIKlYj62JftdOS1vnoEIoNtLOR4zlms@bXsIcbpldzFFxhnCYMX4hocxtQlUKIkJjGdICtB7mh2h8gLJ8htSIiB3uZOrxcf/KLZuyMm9cO8ERsV2I4gK6EX4rEehgQ/6zogeWwhrPqSB0Zd8rgFtO6NVkB2QiStXtRXVnQZmOJtQEeO7ayACsQM4WKU5RCqC2qMR8g1dCtsjNRdvKU6Qoa90NhxIIMxdDx2XOgZnOnMST2jKou0Ll@rSYRjRRK0/eWhFYaMOA74ExwFIcHYAl2Ouhj2VBBXdeAUwMS41gE8z@E5RhCmXk@wfPzOiPXzxgRjqW0bKPHq7pwDgeLB8AwZzZnpusAGT3GQ4GNQMJjI1E5hTAD9CzkrkoP6/dXMZWzRe9OOObuq2nTRU37pCae6y/qo1bggdEAnSsT7XjxZJX9KGQkSFWc8USgpv4sQkSLJUOWJPihKMEg8AEZzNLe7CXGpi4lpJk4n/ZKYBAcm5DIa@1gfT65i9xL8sNGMTqBf01uVDWD4liS4S@hHmGCAImOA7oKcAZ0QRPdyudfR2QVwD1DRZ3uUGoVMeqpyLszLsHthXj4hEJdoeWWehed2ySFFRjUsAUanktMgsUTAd6QEJRTBQ1H8sRU9SNrjYSTXcM@pTZMbLMFFkSQ7D4V9GAAShIwJwofZNSdtX1y5cycQXDZqNWhsIE0B2@wlo2pCMAskA6eGyDJJI34m8sQ5mmDfSCShvBj5kmMDYhO01FqdnU@GLvQ4er8UIBKQVbCxJQeE9ev5U/Nk2rta0TZ6YiQRex0ITWZ3IlYFGPx5b6jdRNX4ElVBlYgjVbHxYnoCfa3xki9WqOhHcw0Pxd@aj0qkhhOIgd9WV5KIJ/X9Fg16b961fJGAu6Czc27UAfRP/NmBkBGlfZkg6LTXeioHgt2Bw2FPdo8f1vy@yAOVjmlXljwsp6tb5L2J0cUg7aODe093n/5CewUMy@xUrnooZq5UwKF2OpMG9lTJyVplMwpjAfh@@2bYmHA5jij4wUxyZhFRad6FwWUWkPPw6SdXSQKSEJKDcgA3/q6INDwOCF1CR/eGVwZhNkilIMswSRCXSQcsgBk6EHUM1wN8nkxfv8bKu4rU2PdHzKypzgEEnsqBHaSTMfCKABYEdfp8RKS0IIWaNs7eLlzRmAE@H6HUfBUZEqUjTeajwwf7T2sE1p@skCiK4k1AltLdngxt3pr2DGFVHGB/4OqylLxAHOVpwnUlgbvdJQIv6patgQ8AUNeRHSZZo6Bo3hBw37taNvKVumELoHeCcFWujMpD3fdFNIIHDnFdVHlXjaIUsBisQq@VI1YYujxsdfN5o5grR4et7iLPXhQozbTCOBDIjS4EnXgS@sgLKdIXq330jx5dQ9wjIRJUASnAzLOYTHl5loDai2SyuKfsgYbmWIb8OXE8kYlJRYkHk61y1yPlMxJ/f2ZOEpkkf6pJiAu57@4eaPeDyP48IM1kkNKAujiOTG4fF026HrQR27GcgcO2IA2XDoMMQWxaW8zdgWNfqyEdPbGoMVx3Af6LEzf6GMYa8zUpjpQqqq7yFRzd9s6AS6uFLBKJKESgFIovv9RPdSDXotxHB1/uwyCi5jOZ0J2hC0gQSUPkQlc34kseTIKMZB@flQUM12Cu9fYgQIosgmChfUYXJtxdBK/0JI4pKyvjr0TpY@caxV868ytNC3x40wJHhGQHnz55dPDp/uPdL5oTLZ9fes9lygUgHOTXAVlIHnK6YW/d4l0Ti4XgYtA3XOxewAWmoKAEU/BTzwXGLWMUmSOwptXw1avEx87QjnvJq4U5w1Dppd3lTegxdj4e1U8IinbPQmXE5UuAOJ5j@xlOJmOvoijQy4fTjgxKq/Ky61j6QKF0MDBYlqKi6nJwiPMa3qoUgIw3N3gKPrkFosOcZhB1a@SA8kILicgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRfG1UbDTcphC6bSKD3QEEBXVsKyEQOmN6Ct/wzqSeRN@wNVK/F2rWa0nCIG0Za6P8Td6BugOiVgtAJSJK@8suad5h02By6NkK4CiTF5iyY5PIZjgcVAkKRZU9TzA@IQt8D5UuQVRKNXU5zNBS6l5DO5olrIK6CWgZoGMquEc27SSJ90h9LEkQCe5PRp3iDSCvteV7f78pbvCJAFue9DKGq28bzZtFsgoDfvEG64mNeYtxpqK1ll15Ns@fGTVWi9S8XDtht4QNslJzRNerI1/KynX2dnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8C4LUawf4dc@I9j1MoEQDla2luApGfqOsmBCyMKmAN6SUAh0KRlpoegriJYHQi@IhtBzgW5EEbDGbwcvBF80jfASVbmz3phP3aOYf5RqcLfXGQESabO4il/ZwfnACo2PY8pFLQ@Uik2ZnRhzn0XWPz1ZCIn/hNEgPuloIgWblwxlpO1wqhkZAqUg9B84B7QqnTYeLWUZU@qGlQYaEE04@gARh0@rBAPgMJOYF2eUF4TmRz3KRTmznzEZoHYOVpI454ZP9ztTFBUSzFy0bRM9qPA5Ao8JF@DqtNHaMLp9l5YmpFKAE6mxkjBycSgDpiliBQUXQ@Sol6oIezlhDt8pIuAwD8CV2dw@4WNfg80XSCJUoaFL7LD5xlV3pS0WXXkNrvkG2wsJHqtiv9OOAAMtrxjRL4s@AknTijCjS5zTfgoH3AnFXGM8nQygxtDBRrzljw76q83GNMJGs0tpuPA4M37QT5/GNjY14JV6Pp8G1A65tdO2gKwWuHXJJ5MJ4MrooRZpcGNqgFOjXil82AsizZAvbwAwlh9fmOKE3KpVsK603VP@p4TMJVQGUh9gSPgBOPFmroTOZFOtnuGYD8nuk7HvYdo66rjn2SfAxCAT83adBlogA6j1K865RRd30ZoqMai4ojQaKmAk33mxkmq3mebOXal7G05g6WdVroB8C85okRvLAdaZjENwauYoEvC3ZyFZa1U4tnolvJRIlyYKM9GTyw1IypXNaJ@IGtKlEsxkHkvrUaXSHLsGbpbVkMiQU4NE3QcuwrERcPi9B/p1kK5mKQ9pkPA1suRaPA126SASPCo0zArwRPTBnQEromDDERdcUiEHS4hR21y@N8XDuRiOEs24gZeMM@mIDAO6TQC4e5ZKvefqoQLek6QdyL48Hwi1O3qG8NJ5z7i5wTJvK0naTYNw9lfojZ6Irn8mgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNiPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3eDgFZhns@UlDqzLHgtEdOiy@eRegs3C9B4cSXLqS@AJYAKDXleGHTBSlElwsAemCdmmYwBdpfwvNyqiEBGc9wdx8vjB@JYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMCkkAKgbak0EYnoc78XTEHNPN1bV3CD6UhDRVv0wCO@MBydKItZ9eR9aDxKJIe9HNI8tToCRbwjz6wR5nXhWv0lC2BVmkddwgjBJQGObEW1tbID1Acb9yTJzNIKiRwwI0Gcu0OhM4z1tM0rdDN9ytBGLYKIPYQKgm1UhtU3CBIUiEw6VfyPp8WCnT0Tw/v7/O5ExpscXjFebT2yOlNQa709aanhj1Is31oT6btjEwgQ5D@9Yn11HEmXMuHl3UzM1xpNkdTS6c5n6vTMjem6zodx6KpoJuSLuJPXU@3dD4JFYTufvYYZP1nx0c1uRKJpOinoxvzxnnI1dlyeh5E1xxpvTVYHvJ4wxQ38yKOW8FWOmQzfkABA6b@Rjqoo8C/iP5Bl8I1FN@/hP4j3EQHsrI/i0CvoacfsUwRcWMd7iLyPc/VzCX6r9XBwngqxeOC4wLbc1Uj/9NJv7/knSXvEwlZk7XwzpE332C3pCNGUcrzSLjbbilOFFCB4oSb7tbGK1K8Me3Ak8OVxcfhJoShYQVLi09BYsHlMxj0LZSrQGlBEZ1vjDNAwh7jKgmxblx7Y10QQr1r8xnQ2cYSjy3ENqgDweCmoEgjbCrMn/uuUheyHX/N0uNs1QGdn6ZVtut8lRt1Kpercwqfld9sA4jtejXYxbQuGuYUj4fRCCrhBimomLSwf62o4TYNjybbBUpSFTwF1ImZlpGas@J@6yKueESGPhObzdmHGe0L0EtwC9rmHWVgVDHDdfSqBiFxX4btzJkEEh/G4hPX3SHwGZaaLZMS6mdq9x2rJ/FVMmgwjOtXWEH@JoVwa5y/A9Iw3WBXHG1L5EmRv0Y21F2De6VK69cjRLbghYCg@5yzi5P06QVrwJB3Kntjy5y02KU8cdpDJMlk6tpXN@txGdR19bkn@Htcamz36UefNTItDkEY6bjyVeK1OAv2fILgDIISbs4FF@7UmZgTkgRoJ4KJ5VVlQGpGiySAPsDgGVRZmJFfIkT9wrhYlKVvgKaaMBBzbz5KMyN5KfctfTIxbN7m@PLjenLzdSI/mxplv@MvOlRYhlZmQDI1MQxQrLKj4/v7T5/K0HK9RHwfV3Aq0B317hAElHWFDigZLXyFfdiLsw8xTRLVdgG6GmgfbT89NOoqNHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6BcL9Vd0I0CoEljCSUiYBVVuL/zOaqlo9nBVp8iigJ5E7cqQBtzaQ8tc1XsgcDDcmtECXOlVUYL2qbCeJim2qSWo9rjnDpGDQsEhqhBI0Gk14Dl4PIImu1qnwPAMRFBcwdIHVFkaqCtgbX1KDqa@ANIg1B8JPX3rDnjYxUbqU2V4GizWX@rl5e/ghchLAM2jNWZruZoP5@rSNzHPhaIOfcz0idvrKlvcI2uUPkc84UPdgwRUyH9lct75Na3oUFnQxZCU3FYEEClhDz91z7bZbCifODzoPJyCORZOch0TUkObu4IBqyTY0RDcGlMl4Zl4H2CYzpkQOleeTvt45KB9Rb/Y0k2GebghioWcsrtRjCRXjl9Ip0Kp2K0XRcOjTtE4fWe0JXOyOreZQIw9SjE@t6yr7pDem2FDXEgcfV1mHnjTp9uq2IQMse/oI6edCEui8LgxCpK0/pQXPrK3Je3kSylG3H6E/tAa0@optJr26JKZVLFLnf6ZjrogIRcF9Y8FwRDZgUtmdNzslqsIEbp2JgPALGxbWXRdGv7j9iS3SH0WECqfznf/l6D@h/vXaGMFDgzGPoaMPQjTUl9ddWlp8UX@i2umL5BPnUMnUiDLluA9nVXSiSboWO1aBpEV6SYPgf4ZKCX@PQNvEGUuMNzYxjzlcEg@fqTFYtqtnAMrvr4l7Zj8WzouUfUOx6RAQuBJkGJSLWxSvBmPElmIiKjWzsdqSCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuV3EFxvrURzjL@b@qYfM5PXO6oBqqPeMY0bqtzVT6Y9RxqfDEI5tbAi7qL0tAYsgTjgLwe30bm6@LyArjmAcTZ4rou2GNqUM3rc1io8e@qNpQ5p4T3@Rh1hdEMOrsXv66KY/omo0LGeaqZFt3dsiT50aCj@bggF95pKEaKZV8hs6Z05yiDD929l4c4C4Di1biqVya5ZWh6P16dHTZLSl8urU8/kLqfHqjkChe9nlfgsGhXY3@F6S63CcGWOdEvSehHnWma@amPCtajhmialMU5xRed0Zc0tqI8DUndq6e7CdUMTX@ARLCOsm5H2h40nZtcBcWDM1KKsasHQERkwiGUGW@MWGeF2YrpFtj@Yq8jYA7UQB3EpdK1mAU53gltG17Spd2BofKsmboiNNBLZWUeprnOGv7XiwxBUU35fPaK9XonVOzAnyepaOozja4eDpclBnHy8paGemZ5Bt9WEPVmJ6KRrrfRf7gLBtF90Gu@2Zu2ZluOxI7rfRKCBC1Tg99UNOkpLU7clmgyPum/gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2tT90@8n3/@a4cLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3VRCdAnNxf2vEecMQu4pN@Wsv60sHigEu3K0u2YNMiVLKCp/qW5MxLrmc6fPg@TMMHetIGwwd4zmJ0yDdYYJyCRwTl4vYP0tuuZtz670bU7oGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR/VqVMi2jvmcKNZN5dxbVt6bG1FipaBx2Xhp4VvkGJePdkcr4xdj0Z@pxcQCPpoSxXvua4TthjeM0vt3ITHTL7Bq3izLLTG0M0vcYVecn4HiCjuspBvZ0vFSrS9qZ/fRmkg3HQZd2ekvYYcj78qHSLZLSknzuGfS7UWPiGh5uEKvlMpmML8BEVlyWXm7SpLJh2pcmvy9lTD6LnBdxcZXNjThX50FkiW5BXMuCtHWKPUUulxXbtI3JHO/vyE07jmO9T00BU@2ZKIqBZElbbW@qsWvijn@IhC2mLjyc8Oj0101a8NHG1y2BPqg031Tp0SWhd6pNCRc9R7ggtfx68/RNZIHptlzwMDfOCfHNt9Z6WdKfDVHlkly8sddxCdXpGJbOH7NC7iZ4ZTl7I7xlpuEv1uLiLl/SXSzFx64wpfEciGX2QEsZGiODXm@Q8vUe2h3wH2sjzRz8rQueGUZXme0b3XURxibwBRvvS2vIEWFp4tigX01wnx/qKRbuJPV913HgYNVvJZEPRvrA4IYwbuKUiwkL3E3D1bqFc/XURYXvoOlCsoWFg/VNAjrViTH3gudKgI/nXajX6ej26bYrnb@Lc6Dv0NvXbWG9PsTaQ2doD40h3zcevq3rHNAeJ9xwyU2oA9aDIW5lG4@XtrhH6Wk5lvUu9ETWyBml4/RX4rSPh1/x5NZ7wZ3rHQjwH7dO3ukTzjvQsbbXDI0pjEueM3HGhkRv66JaONHD7@t4aLBI/bPOIN2o5wNFgufPCv9W3XKgO5PxmB7tsTX16EZJJTqzfJvc1OdbU2hTpOMO5NfOqCP7nrK/b4WWwFezmI456Q7x0Dhv2cbA6XSH5m1Idwx9YpsnSjDlw1/fSXdFyphMuo/esmUCed25jO2lFg0/wsfBukr3Z4/4sBY6bpBXVs3Q0bFsaayfdD0@G4ouVsEJ4Uhv5Ie3K3T8vfJqak4WQCN7mcLpXb4sgY51uPu7J9ZKVnRGYsGG/V0Va1spCekokEtGBgQedV22y/vcIl0sm@W3dQhFS0kYRfalvA@5/b0/NDtoRuZtwX@pfS1tWlo5yNnD6cC7zjD5dH0PRDS8rZ@2oL3MkSlrGLN023@sI7NmKXjIEZ5tkLmmxo1rKvkbF1UonmpJumPCow0PqLrp2jk0yxx7/M6k/tqlOH8vE@jiV9cLOW3mq5Vpv2J6Rp8vgaDrNhFx5Li4ExlkEKmLK@k4g47MnAtenHHZzgCYumSxReQg7jqxZeU2odXVH46Z0hefGgMd91o/Mie4WXNFq6Amu2p70a2wvzbVPfNrUyjZusaGFhv4MqQbPdqPbyvgPdYHZvfhUkWESPoE9nd68sdS80ev63VxNjQ93NEUOm6YmMImxxsxtro26A0rYl6dtw@NVSw6ED8GuTL2qrl1ZzzH02Jzct00rW5OaJbVf65THddtArsRibPpaDz1/MdqHGjPVHQWenRC/t6ZCcClV8Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTriCF@YPiwrlOGv/StJwB@7KUYSC0gRCGwvmKhnMPhucnuCHHtVe0RMr7HZc9caJDcnnBXkHdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBEwvDRw48oaA8wrt8930hSMerKfLodll/cTT5lvEdWt6RM3W7BjpDeyNRtcDP1dgLdh/jiQ4H7aWcRbW0rmNB9wKHtbLLdB17OpHcqX3jqFC4cVSosFmpEGkGLPG1/cfPktHWQLu1b5NCDVD@pp41X7jWbhi40shMGwSx9Xx0OXagS9zndpKe0lbhW9LsojGnLrHr@84qfefJHAaQd1aYgPlPR/eNLi4b3pr3p85jx3ZgNBoDoxw9NfiZ/6WNHqsTYrJHeKod6NO7NZsjArtmEOLShj42OlC/1sL1LmMRB3xfn@hrhiKaGyT9L3Td2lZMq2O4L2nSL@Jep9IuI/TQmJFusb7B8D4oTbpdLhLjfNxSH1lasfHGjmPzO3HbDDzUxzdzFRgK6PbuC@UybsRfmhdYqZ8tF/XwlO8SMXrcKMW6srpGx7H4/YY9SbbJ9wTorml4yiO0cUB@hRyTQPrybuQhxRt5yEI1Akn2VPdokX61qrEAqc7eYwvQUHe7Dq6E@Y4bdudEDBPcwqbDvf1840AHCD8DjqV3p74FxtvQskadEd3WKgyR2nxqdPBUUIeseUz02fXK5DNDvimDyI6u0ABAwK6wUxdY4gloI8nbh60lPWqZquaYbsSp1y6X02YdyTaN7msdZ80cotdibnopHMqsfErONXPVkW5Es8iKTifdV/ak5a1rINBYhjQZuqDzK5ObprcDMysr1kOmIwMXmZdXYdaKro43pMI6q9fTQ@bqGpJv6w94SWj3j8uH0u5ayRPBw//hvY8VGITbhVxgegRY1@0r@ID81LX9x7u0wCeON@mbs0PAG08BrGMnWKw8JIEH7xno2lpXCKg9e2rx2YdBZN/VqEfqmESmbSXJInY9MSTDPpXIENzseokcfuhL2UWTqBOjJ/l2EHClQXoUnP8Ko/nPFQuoUd6Imz1VhRN2Vsj52z9XEfcs4AwgbzkTaezRUxl7Tw4eHR7LY09dOT7tDvF0xDU5bsmwglbKRKakXupuZL2Tb0frmd5EuXekSnuPDmSMsIbefEVDggeuzC091s57@vZGdUVfqwVhqDFZLSA@PH78KLU4oskSe0PXGRnJaPDe0VEaT5p8fLQyOJr6AfSOvjNbm/xgX1WTK5rvM5tWB9dxzxU5rYN0bIA2Co3xIbfLcqtw1XXGRu94PjY@g8ETObj3jtkX1hbyU/3UHGAvZOW1hKKOyspyIZeM7MwGZdtww@e6@jwxx8gtu/RQ@GPtdhSUHLKKm10tPdy04n9VimEZfyfC@yVSM9db68SUoGcMhuhSdO/vi5iqquvofKT3oV5Zfm1lLUdYtT5sOafvsJRs@MqLFHpJE2hVknnrPvKiNALWreANp@d9T3B21m6DuQlA6F1Y2eHPDHuu2xKtZd0kXlQgNW5quzHKl8Y7LEiFO3xO0QL0yjW@cEs9S3TJmbwl42M3kmRv797BbQme@rS8OdZHnz5jT3QPjZDcHDGKsfEOGC8ko5cSzluhBby1y6k9F0BpN8IbjFf35wo70t2eY89nty/C0RlUHNrJuHAIC98okmGZM3PVWNXl81pPVm8zui1vfojDmS/JwVHjND6gt9/6Z6qayZDpIXyqGf56S80EHZwl0KXP0Z5dNOj4IGQNXZRbZPBIrtRGHxkz3I7CZ4NXKfUrx7fCDWNfMbl@OLkprHRDWO6G/K6FoSfLyhn1BoD5G8JYXg6DHznW2dCR93TX8FbsP16J0E0FKd9QkHKEO78uZXASlBYWffd6ER@PLviPla312Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lWXY7aORSfYYjaVfD/e3U@gubW8ZOP6RD/6@Or@zqbEyo8f669UBxGlOVgYBEzSGUzoScT14eYG0AzKvYQ9Mbl@R3XMm@/R2g2IWnnhevRfBHN@fjtdjDLwR7fxfZedLET8Hndk589g9PBq3ENNX6P64P261/zqZloUTg2hm9OHxbtC6Do8ULZLjAosvnix54@HRyeFRxM81ZrN1Sq80W6dDrgxZ5PrpcW4p2@3689MVxFp/3gjEDeDH4XOtHMSZ3cdH11kCqm/DycgKQj7W7cWM6VKF9ZwJnTRcGfhkPqNtlCtresh3sa0Kc7srvJcUexiQTRPy9pR2Gy3rt9vrWuWx8QWtPYAYxCZcLOFAfcNLxiw3DDCkJGs7qnOyEH6W0D0aD017tjJotDINP8P5dGpH7X97ad@CCz/zzE@aenJgpD2RsFOpZHL5MyPRY7NoJTexiVYiN@mILMS9uGAb/rFUCBCDg67@QVw0JgdqsoEnaQUCMaltQja1mpovsx38rkcFhOAk5YheZLIryKvBNs/9M6aVinrJNmpMrIjMP@UbWuDlVmQBLtq/hDIx6URlmxMI2QxOqDL6IAK7YKRYgySv5jPwJivRs/pV/wwvoLR5/uTgyf7R8e7xs6NGpnXpn/ENCmHbkFtgSeDDbE@EsvtkgwGb25Sms@UWZEcfa0CF3AvKxaBkV4pWWyraolDiDqbZPLdtRaFjzop0CfhJIs@NQrHZgReHHZSY6sc/4V7hJ47p4DRUEQctUp5QZxWWWZXxWIfBZ9P2w69@hIZC8SNFFfxMEWbsmwGGhjhwnJ6fo2ew268gxwe7B4@ePd1nAYKLRnNm9ibDWjnPrURz0wtQT32T9n3VWNxPEoe6qtXiD@JAmLgcZxU6mE4WmqGdQ7SAOnik3U@9xRKbBB8oGA8rRfkvX1cu4zJuYU5C3HiAVByyhSZPDWVjY4MdQyNh958efLb/lCH@@/fJG0mEINgxnor9sx/1@DcOAqs1wQea3BGNFGT1Q4iejA@Oiy9OtCPNqeuO13@mib4pQOfGw48ZhF9jEQT61gW02zMyOHfFGFmS7APxz0r5tuKCjKgJBXbRcbYc7b65Hjs1PRNPrSMOfTTDttzYcYMNmR6U2S5@gwq/dKXTBzcA9ak94aaOfIMnMWhpcshy0myTkOWf5xAjEePbG9DYOwYIEcyzTRiSJhX2EloizkhXuFUDSarHryUJQFfIJeHAE4l4zW6bpzRd5e2v/hNlUGXgnoD72757lrkHb7/sv/XB/Svc/VzBhnbdztsClyhCaJvRLwFHJKQ/0j7y6S2bW5JYEA7N0QV8lZkjqKZTojpG5znwuwTseAEn0fgMKg2aG9SYb0GC52e4rQQah6woCjYpFGxl2r9vzPhmuitGIgv5Qk5VAEnpNABIVt0HeEqYA0wmK9BNhFNzXHsBwtL29jYTUbs1aoUqr1ll036eFV@EiG5CXOFsiMg1GKSBJIsUEFb3k8Hgk1KTmBS5V1yNI@PqOTAqUTiOXvhu@4QQWQKIxWlkoJnwGX6lbeLOA2OnHfyuWeSLH5s@IEmFMYlcSVHwbS986kyg@UAnXXzTh9tewM2kfAREK4Ie/3Yh2RjF9ihf71mLI8PBp0X8viYjD@Cgspmrg2m0bsXPEcQRgqiIq5pv4zlrTpp2S@Ftk0Ez/cGKxmyD@5eUwZo2y8u9e93CZOKqfUgkFrt7ZDuoxj@AwrCEpmhZRS0kF0XK5VYWyS@Rnw0UB83YXEB2wKaAZXQN86Uz9nb39g8@PnxydM2KIsWMX40GfL@@nWpKcrrRCh3xaLGWq@TeA@Xo8b0HQUUskC5EuDEwfr8k6k0lWczOIcjFaY@rRVuF4dXSrcf4c34e/Cq@We0m1CjRNTzUzHvkSzuupQd0bupq5lppFbXy@ZtQWsBTIqD3@KHXa6gmkueXjdZ2vWnH4tdbwoqO8Dwmb2EnAFfT29pUsLFfLxwWLPyq6DF@WsyL9sXs6r4obmbRSBeeuZ84JwszZr5HJCBS3iAbYJGCrARR1/a@Qy6jL4ztafyrp9y6V9R2UQThQuYmikdAHQcfUEUusjAV6lvJHIL6Z5kdIbAZxa1lBkb9QkOZ3N5TIin4H5zgGSf8T6rOKjOZtlclksjtCFaa3WR4M4CXFKBDo3T3ZAoazhNnzA2Q0zL6fSNwPXWA/d6fcrXbYB9PRxCvT4@nBi1pAOeWIDFQMh6iymUp4BK@3c1ZCi2bQn4NtL7pF1we9fKJWVIeGrOeOQDenkimgaN9qKotFtrmxEKTLU47LlKdLWrhxq74ER5ljpL9vQy0zhYI6A1dBrXemCXiZ/FkpQX5o3/87PPTeFJc1ZbIUKxvObV31WJsiH5RvZmT6BO/dwbmWFdxi3L5OpcAv6uAueWy4OtH5bI89AT6ml0NJfejifsInCBGJPojfcwSU5tbfZMZvSaaCTtN5rCkOrcoabNUihQqeFCAzChln1x8/E7o9pwllBo0AvT17B4@Xptj1lBluQVuyiTJNvGrZHsgcaEdxKQAOjAkqRDYGjYhUDMAI95JZN7AIQ2GQ1x4kO28FcH0kSaa@XWQJlRqVr/DIl@ZW5YcxXK54lfoMlcsM2h919mhrADYa3wukOuBur5BGKAZqL@yEFsw8uscL0b5xjgiD31LMoBOLGIFNjAwwwDWwkZrd@jiL7FvQ18B@aBSeXb8oF1KKiILLdIMXLOHKxPckHmo4vmfnoFuqixFjVe5RvcRJkPbf21u8gZN0D2gDiNeYamxKBmufih60TZV9cZW7yf0awFi5nAA8E/utQNwaK8xmEpaEbaa2f/0p/gpajGxqaonbfc0Fc9nqnBTq3mWZx9uNiVps5Gp3d3UQYuavJo1QSdXtnL3T41hv3MwUJqiyLIspyhb5@fxB1tPzOda4dXsMquWXp2M1UJDfjVriaVa@qTFnjz54k37TVKcnc5fic2ERp9E3ju8ENUcKvqxSpmd7xSysZMyflmU6Xr@hM1Ab2Un7DVcJ32G/@R@3Yu4dXR3@q/pi0xxkcWaTfyOtFgUFaURb8E/qfsv4OKKf6Mu1@Wd1ps3yYauT2ZzZprm2Ov14OcMQYLUkkcM8r0DnJ7iK6xJT1Kg6BrN@ot5BD0Pt7qGxzjlu230ITOSs11jMJju63Nz@mDy@MvPg@sZXq@frpiQaKVSCUlqXPWutPV8jGkZ7c9@vHGZPn/S3v6zb4wUYwMfh/j49uVjdB@p@Q83Nj68dy@XS2uaxt1PvnzyC7u7u7n76fyTRn4nJ2U2tv/0TzY2NG1bUzZanqe24o2Tky9ELZMT5T/7Ybz95MnXPK@e/T@//qau4q0It1NWBD4BV5ap4MR7CX4qyljvesVex6CVq7E5/bVjgf/5BlPrO8X/@t3DV7FJrK4pn7vwnMRexQqlGHeCA96ywdtprB7bxmiFy9hcqdVq4Cz@138D6esfAxwMmW/DrZ4PYBXmsbpUoyQXsXoBHKqmQb7/99e/HsGQs4kaiXHBdZc14BJzRU3cacG1Rde2gJb@pIyiBPHsyXBiOEwt3VHv4IsJL/CwDTSZbkyaMfxOLzu8y9jTRiqVasltCS75Oc4RKaqqNVX1DnAD6cOtWk3aYtyUYTabv4PmmJM0ozVwYMA07rDP/yGu2CrP6s8M7qkQK2zcfXG/XodCZevZrXqKLr8nUacqlkTHuSuyNHsRBxWk0XrxiPccVhczJU1Mp9O8O82QVNJs0ZLw4vdYLPTBLsuu@i0lgSi@b@z948X28frzf/fn3/vz79Lf9@j3H9EUot0z@8oWRDqFLlGH626l0q3XxbornjfxvQ7tKFMpVUpK@7KZ2AIO1HrK1MxHF/F8Nn7EkP3DAMCaSUoNF2Vb97PH93ps4V3nPvWonx/AI5MH80tBjiWqkTuk2rV4MLT6m0alxmm9JaFAVJMaaiHfkniqAMt6mTXuQjWJWrEstupaXjuEqlNFXnHDTY85MdAMCwEdfXzri7LVw5DFWz3qFasHyeqLOO8bL0C3LsQaDaVl0IAQ@LG7G5WNUqVQ0ZR26Hn9YtXrXoZhPPFip7Hw4tSJLQgaC5vmVb@gKsIXFrRg9j7xQDKKcLBZeEWcV6/27MaL5vfh2oA/@ocrfMX7Bvn43hTl@rXBKuqWllXyHxb2NfZ@lwDjBOt2Op3X3Q6KAXpH7@rqRJ/qM32uTzrTzqwDMhSbwg97DWOyFMvm1c3YHba2SELsTWODPeVcqMVSwdVM3Xo9k@W27ySHgz9JcmYxIfYPcNVVTWVbMD5l4AZCGTlBZ8Y/VRVY7Byu1putxpst6KD11DZxx1Zd8rGEh9y@20pJl5cNcFer/v92PXRW6eIuKFzrMpXafl4H0eN5vZECkM99kLLECKjcrre2KSTMzM/ND95ugfAipbYb2zVnj36QBC4pnnPiBeduCwBvLyF7925KBtddAFDfhP6YTKU2JWkDx8aGP1ZA5FY9FZQKcUiAtHB@/jP@QNGDLnu5fVm/bGxfXm5vw/823S/9J/hebl/7p8fiWhNnEd5C1tJsKPWm0vQZRQveZaWOPrLSBEcdnhCvkdVKrQY64JJb/33@y@nFPfRBlFsyYC3EtthWDA3zZWNbQuzF26/@N/w13371@ygvMvgzKkLsHLu1soXaZpkrnXBj9mObPeaXDW78Ba/ogx6P6@hp85uNC1KK8kJmFT7nn1BLhaSMA3Db6bfxrL/MXkBUFNxgXGKiViqI7ZQ611hsWywUaWT6@WtXPB7/Ry@0cjHOp2fwiPoLz/MeR3BbYAeRq1pGldSLOrfCzj@Y8fOrrn/08@suIXZRZkYFqNL1GKeHEIPmE5MkGKXq2yPcwozrIxKqoqe1L6RnuxLOnegTWv3q8nmB2sF@rVyu86WdzSfUVbbub8Fdhf/9DSgFa/YhbrNf645A6m32s3mtiRa7Y1LnFf49eo1/7LiLf09f4R87fo1/Tyf4xx538O/4Ff7tdvDveIR/917h3@PX@PdsgH/Nn8tm1aq4eU6ESall9XJzJhKBqrGdevPnJu68Yhl2w@y1/I/RZHNllow1f86Y4SfJK9yzH//Jd77xjXitFpfi9ImPnOq4TE1WgfZQIi9evRsXYjW2qW6qGSvTzagdtQMOk2VclhlmhmoPlJO2yjIGy8wzc5YZOWoPXAb8ZcBlZvosM2AZO2NDRAgF16SdmaCrD48B/PUBkAt/Ju7I66iZLoOMLBTU6OuACB5cF@2m0GBxJr4wQL@UVTkjF8wWflOlIb540VS2Wlq5xGRsUnK78aIZb6GRba2cY525sdF80WYxDzTUakxpNhVOEygukezyst3e//R@u63gONN87Bwu/g8PR9HXG/9Hh87jQ2fkwP/h4SH0DaOeupsCDnz3bg04sv/YidWrO80K8fWAt8eU7Z1mPSuhu5ACdq2hX@o9rwVEeNY3mkL8LIHKxRnqF9XPz6qnVXKfBa/gaFcXEYJo3OE/4TqDMSzQN87gOj1DB72h8@zzZujiDuXzM/D6nIFmFf6DBhd9/W/wb/739f/4GUuyRKOVTJxfbifoSuJfMnl@eX7p3@vJRMJ/SWzDH3rAOyY5v6yjkyKdg6uRSLaSl5fcD@6J5DYHWIdstuuUdhEP@H4szJKy5bfEf9snZO1fzXiVAcch7TmfoX4UE6tMX2ycaTZnmUyy2gm@F4DLwPoF7U5IVuljcZudhtr60x/SNyF2khQpn6tW1S3GX7ScVq3mgrdiqVotBS@biUT5@lXP7KgFUDByuWSyWoWXnQBsBl4hbYO9SbEaa8K9decOz6SkXVwEMLO5QiqjZjB1kFMesjU8vetz1/ODQ/qcArCWfAy/Y8JZSSJDH2PBD37FxYp4507C/5D4zm7yzh2tnLm4CH3GY/BSl7za7Z7pttvon724ENsibXQp5@E9U7q4UDPllBpPOm7iU/xSHGSVkFT2oVanXMvAs7VcEYJ9BPLb24VcvV7IgU@hFE/ionkD0W8BvnExXhVj51QGtVTkHFCsond0AxD0ZRwB2PlljCqU5fLJBLDSJAh5lzH8c8Wm6I8t@XwSKHMp8phqucyjJlmukCilyv5fbQPUbpBi@B@KYtlUbqu4dReEWvzzVuoUyJOr50ZNvaydGxWcNr@sdv1v7qJJAuPOnWwZSFTKVJtCu31/93i33a6JooiSENzQk7i7gJYa3HiDSp4vtzhFKtW7VM1qKc@gPnkcKQ4jBCsB0RVtK6@WkEiC2UeLI0ASgXQhtsE2BI2eeBPKnHIb4An6CmTeg4v1WIcN8GIDnP1kJrPoYhbj4XTvdsNIDr/80PCV0uIV@hjhJfi9MMubKIzYTx7t7u0fp7VticW0B7t7ae3o2b2Yiq/5xTsFZ/H96f7u/cNnkODJo/3do/2PDj7bf/YE/D12trgCpu/fF8@oa8X7GftceOm@1g1DN6aG0T6bTs9esZem2TahMq0pFMoZuMwz2lCWsb4oVxV@XdPTX77U3TFd7O0PvvX2B//D29/5ztvf@dbb3/neT7763rfg9yP4fYc/v/Ovy3m8/@Srf/a7b3/7d8DzP8Lvj@D345989Rtf5z96/2P4/eeI3x/7v0g8/hMA1i//5Kvv/vAnX/3K9@H3L/zf96//fvXHq3/f@@b6H6b77u/eHOc7/wZ@v8dhBXG/89vcD5/X4v82j/cr33/76/@W//@p/4fO33n763@MN//ln37/T//z22/8e00r/em/evvN77795jfefvPbb7/5j7W3v/Gv1Ez09rtvv/cHf/WHv/dXf/g/0/@P6P577/L/9vv/9C/@97/4D3/xh/7vx/D7t@D68V/8e@gqf/sHP8D/7/7B3/7RD/D/f/2Xf/sHv/a3v/y/kOM3ueP/@Rf/mt//@lf/09/81rf/6sdf/5tf@/Hf/OYf/NX/8Sv/12/8p7/@H3//r//JN9DzN3/8V3/0y3/5jW/95Tf/@V9@46s192/deP/qHfy/@gfweXc83wXOu5TrfX2@@pnw@ftQY5ELtBNo3b/09jd@ERr4rzP29ls/wsM88Fvz/yNNpTg/4m//H3Bo18uMIRlwwe/X3n7rO0ii/wlIBP8hvb4dviyF8JdvL16ArL@1ItEv/eSrf/5DeosZlToty@DYXdJKqS3Qb7bKZX/89ldsIMkvLkMLAfg5fRs51FLYt5G3vf3B19/@8B@//cFvvv3BL@PgLeXK6d20pN6y3AUR8@8QDyMW3iUeRvwC80/RHJqU@gLe2Bd@4BdffCG0LxQ8NXb3Any/IC9@MR6Ep8r8oCAM/fGYGbtgUbfvzPjOTd83zJmxxosXLVxQBT/MPUWyx1YgGuWzbJYKpqTZLJiaxkizLT5LjXfyxeCZgLfF/8I5E1hqMZmNX7kLp3QpJx7Nz4I7hTxkk5rNInPiJPcQhtyHFoIp31yZYQlms9QMlGBwQA4pCLoH4nitlsKENY4PvHLU6iVGqKRSNSg3puZp0u0SgpjdIyiQspZ6ytpbtRlPmEJ49YAcKQG9noqqJqZKtfuQYW12nyEsBE5gX7yo1Uu1WR3BveH0SM1S9wgnBFZLzepv4L1GMCGdELv/BlAp1VKpegkzxELy6km3eSXlqXBU9hRL@XUAT9zPv3OXsQ9FtSS2ucCIBOOx8Z5axMaIEB3Cm6ktvzj0Hzjpt0UE36Cs/FwYD98h2XSHi6sYAeBKkizLDH64wr7D7kLwjINKUbbwSHEIKWoR1AJCD4aTQSkhRfWbohfIP1bbeu8LgWFhNjc3hVhdzIqHMpFOUZh7UqHDDbjfD9WLChMLZRG9DTrpEeAC6auU/2YcV87ijANmH6b47@7dLfYhFJOeCz@BSamsk3NiHMp2KiVqAL/upITnoJYI0E4J0IUgz2q0UpcS0mnG5FoMw9jh4aGPBHk8rwkpaOZaVsV3XC@aTqcxSCHLaTmd9p8yPclD9h0yhfpPeROJS59SZpqWq4L2VGXoxaKqjgoqMHq@efMGaoU2UFUOQPlk/l4qLVeiQPDgxjMsax6cCNJyZYFr5kwt5BhL0GwqXEmWFFiCbSUFvu2eIxFcibhWKsUpHlBfTmwFW@sKKjUHnEmN1RHR4OIqYSmfDAL3Dtne4ePH@58ej1stJhj0aWijPXadruF5CQzb/fQ@P3KhlQvJWKOBoI8rGjIYYb@SIWZ8cP/pwVGF8UL7VZAgxKq0cOoXs6wKsfH48@2Yv7VIxK@bOeIR3iuLsiW0chaSxupCrGugZoEr4lXaUlIVHnuDe84MdPq0KKbVAmp2SZo/ZsIvOFOGtje5oQ7oU3gQQ97eJgoI9XOJ1ibQCbVVEOp1f1MeU4X60f4xJDg@ZKqWkYX6F2wmY4bSpVC3apZhDybDTdzdJjYzYqRMm41MGv@0bBbuaq6QVvPF1saGdS5hnk2qtnPcpngJr@cSFuMDuJjwgcA@AC@4IA/ce8j8jZ8Hh1V/9x1auUrwLXiimodulhRw0pqDE8aLCxCF1r280iPENr78csLqddCvpYMHQgy4xZAFG9AksycPZarm3tQ1KHTAWM/8zMTP1sk90xtb@hy6DlAjdnl52QdIBw@YVtfolafo4f2ySz4dcF/OdCFmVyq1N2quKGgnlcqbrKYJ4CFsKbjDbQMaAG0U2FL4X9WDTLLZkgKcShVFeGSzWQEnigWhYgiMdoO8ydRqEm@D2ZxKm0EE/BKCPqtp4eXHnX24iJvN8LgYAgFsMHFZJggr8jD/rSDQGxANt7/Rd3erfufM3LmTxUmMbC4TzlZQidkl1M1mNpdFigv//xW9aAVne1zPZtRtZQxOHZy5bUUHZwec@W2lA04TnOVtxQTntJ5VM9vKtC4wYZubu2RoTaMmTowZWtflfmLdM6y@jGeIaiJloInbvvnoepCw3qv1nC59O7vak038hjmefeUJcjmx6thoiK2GJhnotDBLJM@FQe2MTugKRm0go20P19YtoSd3nN5c9iZzC0/jWI5bi4NUGA8CFtANEEdwCmwnm81VGqwlj53xjqDli6mGmoFxBH9qKa2lN4ydYrHSk7uWobs7@Uq@lO7hQR9/WWsnn6kM5C8eP3o4mYyfGnT6ZydXhgRoDQvt1uyUKvl8q9EQxVSDsmnhl385l5I2NqBrG3pPgicuenmSVmpB4p7p1mrx@E5W1SS1ks2ULoUF4ZDmWMK6gElTWLI00v3cZwQV27GB51TSeto8JypU@v3@5dZ5avEi6OcSfwP6XEp6unMevlalSLwKm6YlcxEIPnofyH3ur@dVRC1fEquN6uK9WBCrrUvh7sjomToe@mlmzq@nKgBv5lBjkFGTCZcV13EmlY7Rd1xjETGrFoKIHKHrEXLiZZhdM4M5nl/PrhCJNDu/DiWXFy/DVAFawuUl0J0TG/oFN2Vap72xDbWca@0DI2q0tgMjp1g3sefPdb1eh0o@zxW1XD6X17KFQr6owYBTzhXyJehmmUImr2kAIFculYuX0KKFmK5L9VpWywqaJmlZKatKahb/b3Fo@P/u8TX41/AOqbKacIyWQj6FkQxGX5s9QosDE4cdO/jNmQG7Z3TXxNgb6rSLeM91PO/vEeeebp/woPsmN88ZBj3U8cNb3sicDNfEeDYeoZERw/0Hg7A/6gCCyJp4hHtwcy3HWRWhyJ49WVPKx6FBbCAGt4gN0Z8efPTwOPI83t/deygU2L3DT@9feeT9SHn2aP/Bcfha5KFB0nwI4hf2Hz26@uo/cofPnvanjos/4cHhs9ziFnrhIVUhB9dypNCbgPg3fCVZDwZ50I3yxcChCni04Q7oq3d8Z76wcGbQ@Tk/gWt64VZ7fhi7IhwHx3J1hlyvY7AutyWDCjTZefPFa7VYFoQxs50zVsywnmNZOn5FvL8BnkMdjxgaKGNaFrZEzPrMca3emdkzNoTHeJqxrOIXmxEJ4SEAGU27ZCMA5Au0GtrD73vjSlHHmhpsOmZrPeGBXuh0zcEQxsMzJ4ggdHSdwe99L0hvRK/JzR4Tngf5XQuxrkcXYoIo7oniQ32iz@7GSo2q1xrXM5XKnTvqE1csZ0VvYOzPoM2yZ9CHdHeeLokTWXzA5HZsgGsNVkHNOeO6XgfdoAGSdFmDoXQnpxn1Uiaf/evf@tHf/cmvDWrqVjOzl9neefwoXwEGCdIlIwHSFzJlUje0cilfKme1UrpULuXyaiGfT6taGjS1YhmE9YxaUgulfFlNl3JlEAtyZQjNl4u@iKoEMqmyVQGwdhc/I7xNGos8BNWELw@y1wk9yWJ6@D5logFpRAGVwwmd2d4yazCiMTXDskUGEHXWZbEHD/YyDx6I4j18wb0UexlR7OFLvpTJFO@JokEheyUUcUSHpymhQTZxwl8ymXtA6ikHgLbMRXGIL/sFnOYSRRNf9nYfPMB8@viiYXqIdsJD@IsVvBQhmo0vIDkTgFchNIi2y/PJEaL7@IJZYsgDHrIHYaL4UYAOhjzl0TiAh0FJd3dF8YC/7O5iyB4VO88R/QRfdukSRRdeoP2L4gAcAxd6nih2wIm9QBS74OrOdfDDTzajuWt7oovinJMHCSSKM4qtd09EsR34Yzaf@djkkboVelF5qe/SSxn/RFELkMZo2fAlK4q58CUHZXv48DN9OOkZA37NXf7sQkkfPszq5my6/6Dz0UedwaDjznf3P3qKQXt7D0E8mE/dzqDjJ@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@ZUz5@uATnaOic8ZzRukGVzLvZXYOhsXSzx/RaHVx6jyUIK6Ynz2gMb9frtXZtRAYAoIhBqk8YWRJfgDnwOO6hzQVKfo5H1vyAdi1zWe3UZrEZwGnXmKS@GDm9F1qqW@2hjfR7tXuYuNqGZ6dq1AzXdVwxJlb7O3aNsant6X3jieGiNZGDw02QKPAcW6LPjOQma@5j7D1UHS6lusvsBWafTkcJkM07yWWvyCuSJvG1oMjndLASd05cVvs1lnierL6CV3eTJXryveROrtpL3GPtJPhkXvRf9JnGCrkqfbw4gZCgGxFtsMx6slb/BIQgDvikUgFE/Do@AZiYE4A1exSgJ8fmZbVbs1hCYjOWJPLkqoNaA1Nf4G1bEsWWJDUuWkJdkj4X6tBTq/OYXvOmHfqwBst0VC1TqM7ATy3mqkOoWP35rOrWxlPXqFrw6k@w8fOjehXICVQDMK8vEm9/8evJbSlf435VAnVhgdzRltu1WdVGU33QJGrZGgSkGrlMGtRpuBXTMNprhbRaSGfTubRURF8Y6tP5NHiCigOyRcJKiIyJ6cwsI6tp1VDTicwLs/cimT5JgMxCJGPJ9MTZt6cjBj5QSdgq6RWeOkumtC2LQS04TN@WqJkCr6hiwYDmQzY200ME9dTQLUqRTEosu5WwNhMYZ/N4Ot5vtCqV/dn4axCUkF7tFFLFTOp1MllNbCRrnvFKqFeFOvIVKvV4A9qsP/fIvOmoAXUMLrWoVRqNDhaxmElnM1kondm@GGyLdbGVzmwUVKiiS0YMg3GOEZ2OQ1ln4Tduo@htGVB1almrCjLNjWVLmlRW8lv5DJ@f4ymFsc/YkJIs0RSDs9KJeLyoxePJeBVXBjZEfyoYuBlxsjiw1fgddUcEMUysiGUNIyyYIh2HzQTYgSB2KeBMBMuVhdi5cHl@uQ16sUKbKkFwZBvkkuT6XSFWYQwYY9O3zqRsMPa@ezVT2/Xn/NnEXfgAVyCbuiCI0h4qw0RdjH2GJ/93WBwQ091RQ9OyrYZWhKEMmGMQFTTyKi6GxHCfv1wHCnvngN92qo6H5j5h87mekoLZ@TuMDVKbApU5dnXhc7e2O3i6G2wD293DCd8mCNu4Oyx2Ho/FL@FPiN2lk3oaP6nHYpGzenzC/@fid2PxeBxn1oFQb2LEI9jeeTAVVsFPvCX0CucIjVbyzaemdV7KSnyGAljU5WVsU8FlT3/FIpsrJMtUU8GJqU9eaNBIYrYTeICShJNJMHzl8ziLHVNejL0vtVL28cGhfd99YDB@gKqUa4v1GMuoEp5DqlZ837zY3jhRoY1kxexJOsbuxmg3u1guaaLGPaoxdiLF1Qo/dDU@Kj8vPi89f/zs8NnhAyHW3LjYcHDBgoXb6N7YH38NIsazuThjzVpsVsv5m7HVel1StzU0kFZkFWD/fbUgZS7qvJnXKaCgQcjbX/x@brZdgncto8K7puVTWr2ubmksGRu//er30dbN@f5nu49YHKe5/@5PfqgV/@5P/iXtBItf0tS3li3GICY61UIxdn4@Pj@/hIuH5WOtGEcqV0yCmy/DqLG6ompZ27arrKLo@lYxldPu2lXFj6sW1WTMk2L@glIxH/Mu/CAtU4KgYMWHvMQCVkls/6mZ19S72ztQnJ1sTqtuQDNSwwOfLPzbNrxyTIiVHr@4YAxeuvXeYGBq5FIUVnkjse030jZ7g6stb6QN9qJWx1V7FY@JBqsRW3hsDlfk4vWUshVnoB2xeuOyetlK0YIGqJLPDWPLbl7pBM0NPDex7LVlw5@x5dEfJgo8PHgN3oytl56Y2EoqSq8XGlTbNli@Dq1iSwHctoIlCf4nSc3k21/8DU0r/N2f/OpF@6L9hQb6ZLlcULXYT3@6PbWnntGr/xQS3mDEJNAJaT0HrY2gI9QlGTcmavqpQofcBTV2aqPczOMHmiXqkihzmAPb6JFmKZyinEQV2eZ29HoJiraFNg7SJHeT3apkVRBC@ZTkanfQTRMMtoVGJqGnC@fCBxgEgzED2bwqfLAABR4jGH6dbtuzpu6YTpkkKJ3aSrM7kARy@ABNFG6QbQafk0vA/ZSt60k5yh5RjWQqNjI8Dw0ewiAkfABJfEu81pyNdTQjgjFNG4YOGaMQnhTQa0DeLcjb4gna5Jug0vMIacax44lskL2FD0CYICqYIGMwcxsiVIEtfQAEgDIkfMBmi22zbJKdm6lUdWFN8RK3y6O9Rz0wYSBgMoTWQ5MZQeIqxgMvkPnx24/YLvwaBvEu4hkA4TD46noNtAZMTm8otJGNkXcGBbDInleCisbu3FlgVauZvSSjEiH8E3OME19UD/ZqXAFYoHF92KuIaYZ2KquBb9jsgOIpQhdancQNVFYjSZmIr5eCAP/v3GixRV6pKgqoYgH8@uK9ogskg8RIdl6HXbZdY6pWTLIQ@S7g3iWk6CR5qEY2Zx/K2hdB4CVg@NNY8GUVYFHH0clEv91etWHBYBCd4mct0JIZZwa@7QluqwxZ3cEkSB2mgqKYFsXumy4oOLTsH5hJTGTVJCZbmJUkPGhDu5ZjuK88n8QHpcLYDJ46mvvz89kgM0VdByrUGzs22Qck@0W4qR9aBPAo37QaR3tqn@FnkPy6ocRRjDwyq4YtHzEme4f0/WhKi@vuHRf04IA2aWYMZNYd9ZhWZglqaGQCzg7BJSkRIdwBaRlp3LGMEaB0ZBh07MurKMoAhK1ph@zgPTahXQ0fmDDe2J7if6pbOTNPTOUYP@MgOX08HcatisRQPsPux5f4fZtzluOcMMs8MfgccWLJJovHQF8AkTcNlF38gLAV3DuiZdM4YaGmeSz4FeFR5M5SOpJ2IzFPXn9m1Y1EG2v0ggYf08XPcJ/qdoS@dF0Ivorszb3AqhPZJoJ3OWS5hm/PpRZHSw2hoSLBt09VI9NIMq49jBOgsAZ2ndApjF3jlKGyK@AYA0yzG1hIwV4Mpf2ABgDqe9Cz0NzjxK2gXR/AxO0lutD1fAZvsw9ZVhMwIje65RvIAhhY9bVl6BAGSbEc3qQHFSPThDvyFeidox6EoUUJv/lh@qB1o5tMcS6aN9vwweGgQ3nVGO8WwUs@8oK9A9szFX0DAguA4QpMNhJiCsCmxKTIQYfprybnrV0gXlJh1yGlGULwSQ1QSFTQkeXQV9MX3ysSIOCe7nGj9r4xyLOzM5kslE5dUzY8/IaP59i6pYwHJkjUjjIxRmP/a6kmfiXbh7twSfzTXfJ4ON6ZoehaK9@Z86cg9L2avwMnEe97cRwcT/ETNYMRWTNDM2IeNagHJn3eqpvwNwTx9qe10udB@6tg@5NK8UsEwhiCmaXn6W4agKU73ZN0/6xX9QNOqUMCcKhFI/BEu8Fu8DLyApc57ocxnAny0TCoY53QaipAEvnM7iJrXsIg5jx49d/H5gwS2cYZ23VdfZ6g8CTGxgacmJPYw@Yw7FMIOGGYYefciK05a8xbS8lnYXIY1MK9BC6aKhPObwbKLRpj@IyHzyB8xsNni0yDbBuzFhfJ0OsSi4OtHi1cBjERzDyIc8mt/y5CCDJI30zlIDDmfMnvEn7dGqUO6M3foB5rQcOANjEGghsJpfG82Wi2bM8422qllAE0dpEIATUOoBstoulZL3Qj9a1Ta@x4S142GjaFUcnHG726Q7818LaCZQwriBoGp5eJtigHI3/TAxcI/AIDBJTDIBBFg91JwkxWQwvaFAgNpyEuaMwRa/jItEj68oN8PxCXOOk5YaOAWhFA6B8WCdCEEBb0HP7FtoA7fO46ECeIK9FHpkZoEy3eigMlr3QVzmuqVEkRrCQpQBPIjuJq7WpRgnCoisaVoEgxL/36j6K/8d7o96FfrMaeGiwfMKpCtKvgdkMQIfzuQlRl9VqkXgEDZUu3DBdGrn0un/qjNWSzpQRqBs8Hi@Cd4WfoE5HK7yZ5/dChRtEWK2FTmNdqUMR5jXdL3i8CknKCh8k8P9k8aAh@es5AAEZmZTLDTzaLJpvVapxxsNmaZGcRJGeE5Iwn4bFna5Bs@clAezoIhhesnhZIp7gfUgR4Kh9GQQwaiwy/RY/L4S/RXiOuJvh5LngOtQK/DaGIje2s21qZeyOCdIRpXQGADfEagB7/@GtFuMrwVCl8C3kUJ2XAo/ib3ww4r4AGRiy4ym0aJ8JGRjowCPxiisYB6LtiqiGIKs0L41@G/8R04Bn81OuemeWY6rJnJn3l7x/Es4WUjXTQiPShZnLIkFGTeWb7xkCjMkcMv5M@dECq65w5LLFC2AZ/ZeonVTqW01FGOm5rwU9Ccl95PE8G@gOuqbC7Y2eiT5xcrsKVJpOa3ar8uc5gDmwHvyQTsWsOsl7PMTw7PoFK7ToD2/SMNEOTkyeGr3YY/ocWhKic7DsdTxD8GU2uxiJo3q5Q1G238SPV7XYC9xAmK@G@aNpSiM0zHhdQ/wVXJD2wJx/o4TjhdF4a3UnydphopN9Pdmx2TxKHYz8QZ193GfCwLsj/EDoECYZ5zkJzJAPgKEp3Jgn6isrQGTkDkPqmnixg6ivgDxawESF9PCZc0kxHlbYS@VQD9ZJEN60n/aSfvHdS9omW0JNhem0ZwBIx0sy9SmOkrLsiu/ba7HiyIL@j98f3KIrv0c34khZ@FWeumtd44PtlnU0sIEDEBRrZ29HAogPf6l1DZwmV0BvlKp7gnVHs0baxHmK6C1F3/ehyH9pHOnzz4C1E/LN19L@5AoPk@@9afTp0e3Y0B34zwu2QCfr4lxcsjiYg@kESec/17MKmff8d84K4@N3FByhCgBhLjMtG28XQMcegdnvhdHEA@JY2jzu1rrV72r5V44ErcHJP0@xEW19F99s9w9LnRi/hx0xH4AYlfgoKG/Grdys4Mjpieg7X9RIwdiXDUBjGkeg8UmVNk9HTp8nk@mbFo5hh66GZcsLwYD39MPwaa8YpvhqfrQY9IB6P4XTsqYnTn@P5eM7N41v8y08@H@XjD69JNMxwO0GADnz0VNOLbJM3sc@nibBI7zAihHHl5SKj9eoAIho3ul6H70ei20sKlRtJVAtqWVj@MMzqGjdvqvFIqwjaJF9lercmeVuje@c2F2lqHNiChe293xByDTLu5@h2E1GI3OfGGnPsazwB/Wiezl4zqrRXMNQwJXG6iUnqNskXSQE14wN44oTTZ/BEgANj0uYNKigbzmn5H1NkFDLSxxGpxfcBIR2gRKjISe6jEYklBG6Ifn4Z5tldm2f3Wp7dpTzDHrCcZSSS0F3K0q8FrJ6bqsAy@pM13BmDUHeGx01sGy7b0V2crTiPm/GKmWbx03gFGHLciFf2E8CU47145T45vHjliBwn8con4Fj0rfhFvBJ0C4zgwis57qK/z8LxvRuv7CWSl8JEPzG8IF85XgnrFOLs8FeiCJACyw1SIy6x2Y5fzIlrwMBGQmWaYYvx0qg@0TxMmn4Z@OefeqKPwGAgznFuUWSWYurSoBEZMXg@MGwEHxlY0ZMr/mi@f/iA9kOFUTCbFOh40TQEHsTwWHyZGXHEMJRWNOAJCCLfrKzGiEVGsndEx88dWihV8nL@RD2Z5IFegsIbELm1yIS@7@WnD@prGQSvwHfDExOvw/MaOkF2hBGuySZXoIVEfRG/oVBY18u4@LUfrSGa616OBNhKQRReSwQ2wtNBhqPFOcxs7IyXGwmF4uZ7M5qGJuV4p8TWeyUZcQW/Z64JJm@/ZMgYop0/eVNxIukQtSUWhIGNTIv3snBcIF6MQQteF5FUeecDFCI8B3q40T2hb6fd950Uj7ObNI0V64ahIC3PkjjXMpuExDIamprqE557qLzuo/mp91Nfg5QznGtJIIBIyjAXzl@d95DfHS6/BwJ1QIQrGawSrFcPpdfF6xtH2SuYW4tsr1cgBqbZ/eRK4SjMYUFy0A4ikvlNbe2aiI9bPriQzzMNoV@R9gOyhTrBLXS7qltwWCgluKfLnicaeJ5o6wl1XSKxTuVAaJExJx8OL3iI6aJoN@PKC76qijGE5rd1670r2F2u4GjlITwqgHuF5LyXu1Obdrks@jawbe6DLFWtMM7Iabk0rOaFJ7B7WroNl23B47D9/3b3rVttJEu6v6mnSEu4UZlSScIGY4SwBQhbe2PwcLHbB7C6kEqgbt1aJQzypdfM/DgvcOb/PMJ5lXmH@XWeYp/4IjKrsoTA7u59zp41vVabUlVmZGRkZGRkZlwOtvf3dt/Tovv06VNXr9GTBD/MWpy1xuu4QGbj6ng9mLFtWfKQ4AiX3TiOjy4Ho/GD037mliwRYU3KQECtGPbTc9zVssyS51Nzl@pJWYuiGtYvyTQIUlIJqk6AJbuj6TomgoTj3KNAAzHqLdHb492ay6l8Go1@0AsbDV6@TCJYvYphaMyNuPu37IPCVTTiZMySh@racTjig9reV@9eVY/U0aua2jne@qt6v3@s3lX3juDs/@Z4c7e@pej/2t5hTTkpq0vk7MOGkui6HTZDJGJVS8XiE8WQtwbDicid3JYr7w@Dnno1aIa4plqPgt6LS/nh98PxhtSq0XZ0gjPMDudo7HXGsLfgpIK0jYVy02KHQXgDKCp7TnvaHva8vUGr0@5QWQd732EnjIyPmep2aARJ3hqXZ0@UJOQPZNMhzgsKC6xrqh5QedzdEJhA7K9AYpSQhIMtX2nCxf/9bgoe1Q5eHyrEjdja39uuH9X39w7Vzv4B/Xzzvr73kuhZPzw6qG8e4xMXfL2/Xd@pb1X5hSBQ9BUCOvx8FY3vRcFHcaZK8xfcfPtDGv74V/rUGxq8ug7YdTJSC1d9SJ9O0O18ClsLZecqgvoCd02@KlC5@erBy7e05qvwV9xwmqtgtj/IHEec03K@qNa5NZosGzTfynq60rKXL7l8H9GbKKS1Ccsc6CHHz54ywNmIp9UJVWYLNio4@5Z4EDyXDWhq6AHBBihjsFJRnI5qYcFbZ5Ab1FqzO0DwTmlNjAj1D1R9YUxNyg5TTNvKACj8Hep9nAeVyvEL4nt6saSbHY@kgHocv5AC6om8gCpah@2IWtYlrsb7VxDPakVe/Nwb7vC1sHoav9gMeBe7qnGSceMhDVSczg/RMbqcdExOeTgxKmeJ5ioRl0dCrm5XJkYoqSBJJspVItu2UckMCZs2rhq02ZtkWMZX4gbYCQXtcaRyFddXRzAOCvsdSfd20Q36YgKVmO4w76lVBCKqbGj1IU6Txh4kwwEzIFI0pvGI621rrTD83npUc/NWi4G2keRUpcYE7VsIbN5C4I@AIUD51E6nySsVe7MCzKCtWTkXDYgjcW77m12e2Ll11QxTFbTVVu7nzqdPriayl9onGTtFxo6G6FM4IrWSrzLbgxHNcRarnFgKUrB5ORiOOzKGuXQP@MaJlzkqjYWNWvvJEFe3BjpMt9gf9K1Gz4mL72j1nJjye1pljpe781h8JRmHifNpERa7O6ATnA8@htbdmYdLpOsQxy@kCPNdOQ4/J2PGRPRPJ5EdvykkKl2tbGxvnuZ/@8lDtlIRC5Is2Bgd4n9iTLRF04Pv@dhgcQS9S880k2UuujpHbW2Dp6UlZrkBRvvAyw7t6140yvE3MTe@/R4@NtPv@eWXLxWplYdk0hmmo8tcIt08dWKa9LjOmdImIJbsJGRJ1ufMG49hxvL6BfxqMAqIrNOHHMG@fSqHmxYhpnfnV22SLDqVrh7uGL6rNtiiIslDDn8ZezwKH3KblcUNt5AYlCiLnDkjoj0DueS6llkKr1e3wG3fD47k9/eDW70XO1kefhe07Xuh/S7c8ot3w5JlyYL1/WB/uwesLG5/CCz13bsbsCySt6HFnB4zpzefja1p72/xp1tjx3OPwGDtxQlKDNRq7arPV9QmFHZOKrg2mEQhOjzarh0cqIzsT6guyT1sGVpaDAL2A/Umsbbt9FnY@bHSFG@WY@XJvElZtJn/7pvMM4l3h6jQOoin6RELiyTgdrtzI1JPryysQrD1PQtEQ7k0dp@NDIpONOCvtAckZJNBszrozOxmVhafTmQbgWu6eaIb2zb8bGEtazcS1I4mNiDbJii4gGfJ7PF7J/rxmmlHFCzEIUKHW6RJ03pD@4RDanhIBX0/PYL3DIsZUhjZi4KdNbSD4VcxrWH/eYZiRhIlXHRhS6xr5VijJvrxvFFz2CARy0AAS0/9USya6YMR8fxm3R5QN1n0cukliJRMpCx9YXMFVT/7qpcwpka8TlZihdyea/OMzYnB8gynsxp2@e5CD2ELvTItHqabIml7b1P5v09TskqkWjI0n9kZ85EgrywvP/4W7OlemOr5Pwtb1pBp@TnuDWl/n4CMJhEf7xPn1vc88z1hgHtIJ6b1ZsJMVSRVZ8aakuo7L0Y2foSLnAsRMogfjyyw06266mYKt9nQZUWyoXORW32wpnDcUZk1t6j/9f7mIJC/2d6D39@eTDYUgungV1jlvx6MojDxyrNCvFiv4A2bfheORn0uJv5MPUDJsRvTvc527G0nBq/SK3zk@za7J23tnSRmt545a@BG@HjRR@JnnO6Vp4/38qWy3dWd@m5NPeJ4ku3UWWRmlHEt2fOg078PAZbBfC6B5YN9@B5Ga/Q/4eAZkEQm9ubLMW3cb@LGFCGt@YSzCWmzUC1bS9Oj346aQR9BQbzMw0hlvB@oIp/C1vZ33Fkn68Vyqj4hFw37OarlZfJ@hqvSOxzoAlIahIwm3lsLFjw1jKUk3GsuBrCPwsVWeCOnZ2w5GRRKq8WVZw73ru@Nvd7JszPvUbOSUbT4Bv1edDW6bv1yMbj82FZdNfz5/KY5@fSrUstP1GNqa@kHCepbWqkUOI7qU/p3VT0rMudqBJ9zgGIkIvYlQ6tSCyrZh5cfKJcfeNO8Bg@JKS5Vj3qGC@FiN670TlbOKv1Ksdw76Z@V4eQ3XqyMF0uLObz4gVZRkjFyM38yPsOaap@6hv2PCqEzOROodg1R7BpCb14Ho85gt7r3MnUaBwUAR2Da1psP1CXp8xys2eB74vfD65w@JvMUONaBguTMsVdQCa7yfJ6M45hWhzCjUfFIm41u@N@J68wV/avheMBfTIREsJb60vnizBk3piKfKFCRk46Jowj/AoKTlMnhYkjeTsSKOl8Sda0E30nXAnGCmiwOM6eZDHwKgaj25To5cyI/DJqXQAJZzr9wNbW@zjnPidUin0/xYMoRjNhhoniGR1yA0J8h3zagCdbcI3b7cKj7@F3Cg7zhM6ox@8mwgbzDmiK@wPxbfWb/Jq6/TgQQws@JzuXrI06teZEiKb6DfLiAkGfpjT@uGeBWKYMyh84CtrRXSYCzpTjTCM1qMtH7uWuQU2hF/@ke5Ev861Y34vKuFGeS8D21/hWBljyk/GkDf7pJtZxVLW@qmcIWKea@SQ2cdNH26HVI02qitsJul5AWWswl5MAj@/fq9hfj9qMTtHkWIy/f87e@51PfffkuSCWlfFrgk0JrdqFM9nNS7qvKJMW8W21VFCsvPo100yeVJClbvq9s5I8HjU5SeCMeSuHK@MN66kPe@vJhxujLlwepOjGDx99P5Lvm7yU98jGWqbIv0u3jr6MHKGTjWW1rMsWlfr/Tfe7oBNn6C9gsQ9RUSqpzCkRlJlVF@2BqcUIaHM75edpuVBIoiyUjcXjOZDbWX2R8rWQ8z02jIV6MtybWjDliUYnbXGTC3bDDIrXDnx9YIBgmGE2ZmbthKk905YkFFqUemGbFC/LWBKeuTU/xCvwiv@AfM9nTyJly2dkf5wTzG@m8eDenCcRC90FmNpnS0gTuIvJSd@qeVSRpezINcbaQ2LNOgeM2Q/HBbuMY/EEsJ2xBYSTFLbrHXzSlkwIlw753DSE@fnX@VnjkvAxIxx52wxtVxTYjYC8sJ@XgPg6jcYTYUBziJroaDru4dWSF75pdqHVYkaVlXLckEK2V3XfqsOyR8h6etEM6VfLVPiBfw0Ak@RBdXVzAmQwesINriFacuHTGvlPtT@RAg@bM4yVxMw8Vgm@wAO52LmwkZORk9oDS0TBohr5DOlpE2o8jXW13dOpQPk@H3wiij9GStuY4/3TVaf6y9RL3uU9Lxccli2Qf9XVw0X/8JHGwIiKZD0sIILhceuI41t1wU@6G8wDoqV0s9G@JN8OPYb8fOlVaMbhgREprFI4@hi3fcQ7C@BIYcMHKuJmEH/bgatSUwx1SugJiRngJR55chxGH4S/WZ7kubvJdmefg0iq5baah/thpgYDG46Q9wO0wX1ggTIDQA5V64ZiI8shVaZT47lnjwrpLDwdRRA3EObHuJmIy9AfjTpNGhk@ynC6BkmuQpLF@awoTaq/ZDeAc7M9CAO4xCQUMAuYq6T4cHH1p/rtwULpj5o49MCNTIOk34LlC0z0cdUj6JgTmUeFqFu40wEev6ofqcH/n6F31oKbo@c3B/tv6dm1bbb7nO25clHM8XvVqf5ekS3ybLrfm@/QiUz2kmhn@4FT33qvaj28OaoeHav9A1V@/2a0TNAJ/UN07qtcOPVXf29o93ubbd4Kg9vaP1G79df2Iih3te9yqqeYk9dT@jnpdO9h6RT@rm/Xd@tF7bnGnfrSHxnCrX1VvqgdH9a3j3eqBenN88Gb/sKbQMWe7fri1W62/rm371D61qWpva3tH6vBVdXd3qqP77/ZqB4qNBKxebtYIy@ombWHREvdzu35Q2zpCh5KnLSIeIbjrqcM3ta06Hmo/1qg71YP3ngZ6WPunYypEH9V29XX1JXXOyX2DKjQuW8cHNURLAiUOjzcPj@pHx0c19XJ/f5tpfVg7eFvfqh2WlbO7f8gEOz6seQq5DrlpgkHUou/0vHl8WGe61feOaM04fgN7B5cG@R0RhrCsUtVtJjDMINBbItL@wXtABR14ADz17lWN3h@ApkytKqgAi4qtI7sYNUhEPLK7qfZqL3frL2t7WzV83geYd/XDmksDVj9EgToMMt4T61Cjx9xrjBPhJY/ErI7hXI@HU9V3VHX7bR2Y69LEAYd1zS1Mtq1XmuY@QvVahyidAc4Mgp59sNK@/epjiOCUt09kZp/RxBGTtva3a7Qi69BWmeTDMa06q1OhlOxvtNLEH@lnKmRNKzy/umh0@u0BfEzjanLw0YsuPGTwcZH@5NS5J5GVPl/hCtlso/G22qCN7mGj4XrfUzOFxrdq6GPw@0q5uo/Ii4CdNw5@1taE7uspQm38oC862VAPFxAoKdT/QUzfgl7oqkKhFepqcN4HYHN0FMm1ySWuUkg0srMj8rYkTfLJBP/uaHbgijkD3m82cE4Ky0guNIjon/6X5IcsDtYLks5y3FUoYBPLaHQ@haYZaYRDIvA/OiJBp81N@lEY/nKRK9rNYc/vXwwGrZzrmjpcdkz7wIuc@43q5@HFVPX8dH1Glq@ddUqByOy7WYWJ7581yZQeF3/EPcvhn8aY/7gGG4n5gFNTbooPq/WhZe4HqQ6LJE/p0BZwr@BBhs73uvpj/R12c8WlJ@Wp96/i9zK3YC@IMLa04J1wvTP@8@pMCtAE41gcRJKOjpBRKFh1jL1JXPiaCl6i0HWnBcsfWqsvQ17XiSSkyF4FXbtNrMajzo2NPcnhlwfV15vHOzskOoHtk9XlpytlJw679aMnf9@jHY40y1HHhrSOk57Gn6xZskWKD88UK9B3wv7MwIUCCiKOuxk0fok4D7HdRtqSCYIM3Y2QxKgPE71MCDpkFAfgeOAYfp05MzUD5FJdddGbXnDDKn5AuhLzgDZm6U541G7wD2DH099M8bhDmoE0i3HsXeJc2l2w3MvsGFNR3txw4B4U8TOGjyWMW0wDPupi@1l41/IvzdvWKEZiyoj5ysPONQmJB9NYKGNX0ZeZ/YbjjOgDYI4eRm9@1PxGj@91gDsOdxdE4@r4kMi4E9fEOXVyGK07faIhnyGnBoKqmZbWFU75XY0Uzz19nBwHBrFmA6OChC2w8U0DLsdxRKabZAvYFwuu@iyciuAdgFPWHKt/E@fO6o6GUjbxQ/RvE5VCCaw4yIlQ7TpuwzFF3sdxLAw5U2T6U/Rg@P9AmsyAv047ToKeUMsKAvhdlGSoQivavjJROtfmosG63Uioab96n4D5ag/MZdwxfXtzI/41RAI9OhPz4j2HPWznZhAATI6DDXv@xiZplwFtnV5kXF0d9yT9Zm@YU3qtMEvFLbj5lTOP1S7P3K3gh6tcOWuyGtylquqFbNzOedbTlmlqK68eRhkB55r4H4VHfAAST3jm0kuxWp3mrKKeZUYO6FBL1oLTiiMmkVr69c5bu0fKCpGZkv365ssQikBvAJ/b/eQEIwMl5rnpiIu8EqsjjoKHeOLYJmPx0SHrztkQsxsCzsMWH4YgB8n4GgtEV6BzqL4Emso9ZEMRNJJYHSZxBiFuXZ9Iy8vqdYw9n0yCQ2Psj/sSyj6UUy1TwpcAHxpD213eV6@DCaHc/b5uC4sVHh0OPNguojE5ltD1kW@lORiMSHUM0G/C0etMXF@904cOYT@6Gun4hbSedUb6RMIo/dQM1CbZvfMyIzHkGbWoM4a3Qstn/uAu9UJYiEp4kpv8isoR8xoe3TCHjp2bxZLKrSdf1okmHJaUibiuVtSXL1JKCKpDhoZMwU4Uby7YZpPbwb1DPP2uB6NfsPZDBeq3wlYcmdQCyWeBMkj1Psd4bI6l68NBxCcaNBQ4AYkpUZKDtNhQldbop5qdtF1TJomOidil3JPf307MpMZaihpKGFe3Tsy3kqfBBJWWdGjQOFhoaWmZUZm14fp652aMo4Wmr61V5rQfi5Q1USIqD43qiCeRm/HTezzpQ/7Kwwizh97gjluroEAYOivuVW/LOcYPNgXvOuGoZZ@JkibTCoY4fuOtz6DPvGiODnXYv2YwjsIJ7QCahc5NgWE0cn8ZXPYbW4NucNEZdALapyEM/I1IPDxO@BEDdjEaXEecSog/tKxCrUnyLPFlJAwbfsf3kmUrNFc0Doc520xhPJpULyVMBJ@cwwgwySzK/D2cjpEW13mynFRy0v6nbI9Xcst31n1cmlVZbvQBQAu4jSkLCvEhHbNjkuV8Wr5V4Py@AhaO5yqvAvcOi70Uxs@IRHwNk8LYIHPLLMHuBHZmd2J80rrxWhyDcIRAS@F2iIw4UY5fewGSNZMUeQ5LgTVVWi1aVeUW5QZxCPEwuZvcS0//wdgTAn8C/dLjWdwyixFYxLVNtKVI9is6yijhwuaBHZbRLIlJinUuOn3L/ZCTUNxMQ01/ntxFDbb8IaVIh9m7xZWYkTna@CDjXa5BIqcxcbGoLKgFl@N2QAWpjnPFuxk2/Jb9LE9@XOLKyRkE05aGnLOQvotUTaIS0uFOmdfaKEtM5W/PmKWl7x21KQJWZpmcWWmZcxmjubAHSkfWV1xrDUYkjDNT1NOmHgvReDBc@E7q3Sk7ZkZmm0Xrput@0xBYmK1Ci@WjFpO2MsHjpOxM4zPFNGmKsaUZ8RC2r/wcs/k0EW8qDcy3SmPyDTrcRbPEbipeVOLxbsncx6L4ERa9ZqGJpxTjjiCl5fj9SYM63rhbgmiYsr1qsMRoQGQ0JvJogZoiU0yl76cQc5/GfYoeLaIc2m0R7ezxuZOo00ZyJuSp@ZQKcgl6InA7nDZJLg3bML5AmDjRcGMhFSucN96Er/JK@XMEGcYHAQitOMwn51BygpsM1hQfcXaAdq4Ba6ESJBE9bdgWDnHQ/5hgHJVfH@5oi4fGJF86KwukmxgS7Sq41H2QjL85/Txp3DCUW6SgKT6DFHGPbsmmy@/v1Z/tC5UjCFKbP2tL36KHzrhqkbChf@xPjRvowElTumZqRqUnQoNFA80F2qVcdEPZrkL764yE42HdoKcRbSDkdQ5/FnUNhPNeKcbURpWb1gRFXE1umW2uym9IlYSh5DfIr6eiqLq8cSUAoWBM9SslgoCwpow9LgU49I7NeSlE9RhRxUoJ05JeclTUxM5zxncQVRd4smyVKM4q8cyGkZ8JhBSL2WUSREhnmV0kgUIL3UxcrBJPZ/cnKUEKseF9oTgNhR6VNA3jkRMCcgLooptIlJOS8oqag/njk2U39THmb/76rGh9LU5/JfrEGJ7kS9NfV4upr6lml5bSVVM1iR6u3WrqI5HCtRGOpcKf@49dU@yQ57FNqLXJSGkZ2j4bCbppl0n7Nv/nSK2zU7bRMQw82zPcbL8akmIlFZT9/gDsaoGvDBC7/U/31limGkx0rgCOS2ecXXKyIWSNNYOlHt3CTtdE2osDFJg97aCt3h7t7KTCvp5PjKFRLxwtF4tFMPG5Hfze2FbjKKkzKKRLF9pX3W5heP2X0dvzAsv@MOSUAGtmBx3SkNCkiPzB6EIyQwAHKorSee3Iir3@Vbttp2DADSUGj4ZNSupoCIoXoE5s9PL2iA@AGKReYH9CB9G/n1Q8@64DUTQ1FHMNRbVhEvwxY27PiDx40YZ9dnxTxcAgmI01E61bbmXjM1YQZDbhweLwxe7nxDw58yrsdgeeeodkxIgUMPd1usLOjl2hKEVww8jevVcRx6P1VPix07X8ilHE5nWAMwuTyTNh4sIjNv5BeFG7GeYyJx8ytKxQlxfRzUXEp/ZU5iLj6mDx3wFW@JDQ/q7SvWCYazKdpgvTUq9ncPJEGD0ueTP3PqkiLp@JaZp9uzSIOhtdn4M1UNdd1gVMLHseXu7JHcVj4mZOb0pt0LAoMDROiLnyfTXgavaPE4sfx@3290lFTgMgA/u7JKJkQvlzApHvAHgG6ulH9EQU7b/maVrvTAUUEQUHyTpuyx1UaKCC4zxsVn69zlWrVTU/XFxU1eomPeTzqrpZVdt4sbmptun3Jn7/UFlaXi6LzN12P9PLTfPyq9okGHzCudi8HG3TT/pWgd8YrLUxxPOFyrxXnm9U1jfKUeGkugm3fnr6z3/5n//5r/@rUNU//h0/NvnHyYe4kO/7hfnm5/kfvpbx@2T7bGH@/GR@eLZwUQaX/Y2jhg/q43yQmI/6o3MnK6uA9ZbtSM0@m6PP6KrK5ATsBaNfSLqsqWwzKmT120gyR7GMzTZD630IP8pz2sKbpAPTW3lCIktAJziOp9FphjDAo/WGKEm4wA5U6svdijm4RziYuEB8q5LVkXhYZ/0YwqcliaQAX1xasfKdfhT2cQL@kXVe6Z7jBPS3M25o/i18eB1dbA5u1KPTnHpUVI889SiT4T@llWf01p0vdOCdK8VoO5DJePQluVqAmaGKOqzo8f6Bc@1Mkdtx5jllDyCZMBVcWLzgvHj3x84yknAtunDmkIpTyREJXzKhSvbzfP8rDctnKvE1k3K1YUWhoXcx3Jh1oxKPL1SgIBJDgKTlnhBkbUBN4qaPPZLxVDBv9Fg7nE2IAYOsBy93eN7jBa1F831t85zaSyHNEZvPy1usjWVxhma08UXaTxDgCxXZThbZk3Ahu@CIlbfVS@6meGHb/dPMJ7YOk3BsbNOl0m/KYgKx5rYJN9/Xfi3akFuuV1SmE1@vWE1lpm2/lWNV6V11x52hdlfg1jGhPsetfZWZhBFlQAJHYvav3Z5hfFBgIkVNDYsky5qo1gBdl5nQ167pNMCuLzdHFhEKH3I0t79MzW23wF4ihh2EBxip2JSvHXS6kY66MmJiXwSjc2QHDNqcUG0s92Z8nofsq1MYD9ox0j5DZpPzZD5TV7LDUXDRCzyV3RscjYJJnZYt0nzGTd@lHiIEE5DA5NNNz@qeQVh6pIeEKRJ3hS2HkLygO9Hp0WRsM7HPCYbUTAUddgWTIMVOTMnwS2qspuiYcPXvGAQb5VvCO76N1CKWJS8sjTSkjO02w9Ps1tRxTAv23IknTsYRVOOZaXhBV7rCQtvji1@S5F3ECNBtZ7QXoHZFWHmG9rE6XYT9ILU4DbuOcfQvlJWsi5jPnIpSrJEckye1lGS8A1akR35IR4GQtcmEM3Lmcrm500inc8va6wgH@Y5t8QuB6sQJ6DiBGXuGqON@R4Tl1AqV5MDwVZ0t/wlCuxtcEH6T62ACVjzN5p4/KLgnH077Z49yp/0vp59cxkSLZLPK5lVWX2YbiaXnCq2MBS/101ilRSbU4Gk/XeC0r8SHxSIBIVLInXwonH0pEEKnWWSlP80KQVJDBkwK97dXAPjCLTSzaSwKWWfOfeSawc89L7mK1lb@izGUF678JSzMppKP6WmfM2oTKPbT/fVKXE6iwupS8clS6QnthC7Cm/wovMJ6m4@uzsMbUiUibGdp6Tn9lOKGFCG@3kRBmV7eUD8lrYn4nkTaSUmLUD3NuR0nZiuq4wtPUHmiModLhYuLG5cJcPmIDb@niOVMWY4FJaaDFvflsH5Ggx7aCSLItWnvEOFIWBmIjQgfoeYB2SRfuYtDXTNdFtjPyVdbiN3KQGh4C1lrtegP@nmtrLn@QhlKNLxmuqvF1eL0HL01RVMzdF4rUwsPVGnj@dP/@Lf9X7Pj7MZS4d2I/o6zv2ZXVrPySA/067H59TG7kV1HsZWv2UmB9sD0@PQ//jfV3/gLwcGXyTr9s7FsYK1Mshv5Clf5kt1YoYfS0hK1@3/@@Z@pD/OyY0Mu1vmGpxixsqHIVtBn3qXvqo5eyrZ0IREr7JgFGGJhSHtz@gHDqJul1SIf02W1VcXHUEe@MvYoeolnw6wxmwrJSYaxpyDNSCpU0EBeQBoTiraybDeM2QaYN0FT/fTQX4loB/CTNueIm4xNNx5GMBmal20RDWBOWqT9vDxsFJ9nYvOOtYyxKSkbFRJbOy1rVx@XiR3eDMJxp5m2kjDTtdcMrsNzH3zoh60r2lP1o@7g51HhI7Fkr7S0WmjjcL/AdtyFIUPKDyf@J1IEdTIg2hiy0amnRjQCgx5CeHmcLYgU@p34TsrkkyQtexg25QwrnZOYioiPnyfXw@iOn6jSOf6XFHhkztSJIK1caad9qrl/sKYyi3FBKcd7XhfYvGHjWB0CIy/WsEOWTb7DfcDpoOmPXx1dsBMS10LUdSniB61WI9Dfcs5cxqRK85y5y7A7rGTaEt4dsVNxY6LpL2rmnVDyHZwg5PMs6ACrF44D2qJXMvwG@/GkBYRJ0Xetcai4hKxtXVbv6lsVzrpyT9PX0vQ1jSi0hKSdmGesaGzKLiaypYKjylHYwJXazIaptcgkbR75/AcYRDIs9TbcEnR32AOSqJZ0R1uV2cPm8V6YeOQ6FJ89OVqUzNVONnF@9EwJ8aCG7oR2fWmMBASi4K7BQpl@H4oHRMWkGe30HYnnN/XZxPfQYLgP@wglaoetk@Cjsiz1PyL3TWfMvpSKSKDjyto22I6sHjHoOMRWnII2g4OXjAuWaq/xZosLmuFY4zTQJiRUJiPnVCdNFaeXbevstZIogl5kiqWlx0@WV56uPkOWsznd29lgUMnHLmB4GRAM1qhztMnG@0ols5CRV0hBfbtJQJ8FFhdwMOu6dl0T9vnafVApFTWwYoZhXXMaDamujysZZAJxFPpYEWiPkhtlcrnnayfo2Nlpy/1C/xN/m/iAzHAmHG0gpLfG4U0SmcrpScCBCgtmDoqTe4wIKq7@YpcNB@0DRJsIYesqbE8N7SICxPhyNLi6uLS5w9ehrY5owhDBOS41dlAvw3ESYMzCCrqoPnCoW94XFQPv5HYPYJSLJQE6nwCnaabjVgba0hSzY4EWIUTWhMcqrhAt01GbnZk7@wNV29ueRixrp6FjuL5t2UrKHUcyQwAZ5Oq1untE1NXRLtiVVMskLxVVmQVcEeVK7A4fwFe6iUTUFlWMrGa9YZy7jywl5sUktGlSlcYReM2AWSp@m5TGr9X0AgQxglCfJsVCzIvvc2ySJTjZg4x5Cl7OrFk2oq87UcQB5nRjGVdblHIhziow59wBEOc2xYx0pLiGEeXHGideltFGMkfxisbRgDZDjneq4cySnGaCrW4jCYCNrOOGFuh/fW/LU9s1@mfn3bYHRXmz@lf0O07xfDe@JY1vaU3Vd8wQ2NFi2eYWNlO/wkWJmKWoA8YmCEL4tiUrYphEDajVdzTtZVKfpOb2WcIVYNdAK@HmdFRPEgR64TOQOb15j0NxsLsOv1uTw6vbkiYOqaKnhRxx3T@xLZrMJa3GkISU3wFiaRpEHKgl4fa5hOHFAp0170DvXQxj13dm83SKZWVDRWr7ToHInubZOylzH1ssabZYWsM43scXzLf38sZ52B5oX7SYOb7BGw/@GG/kv5858v8tmKP2j@GOx5o7Hq9B9gh3xGHD2aOT07APZnDM@YTX4Earc9HB@VDb@olOFD0LAAs8YAgfUvpYKqJvd4gTlZv9YXF6PYKR0NIyHAP@UOef6M4/WYPM5cft8L9q5/N/584v684vr2GtmTHyWrWzwq3/fXqcqIS59IuZwwt1V4q5f7SnK7qnK2tYTWcM8//3nub/H/X0qe7p0zVETJALBwlffz83iyZSPdyq1xNzC9/RQbtyyGM/mytd7L1alQxtHtrdq@iyAm1d/WH8VzX@q5BG/IQ0dLiLiG1D4728bE/FWV40Sz7lUHCykp5If01kdKu/esFK9iN6gRIhzQdbI71RIYXck4/JbZOf6I@J9I0Xn@/FWWS7TpaJi3NrAy07wpKbTHHRfHWSzKWVeF3Z5hjIauvoYHfxfwgZesEv2guNkMfQXofdrllJ7C3YURx1SnfG6g5gH@o9R4pVNDkZ2bH29o7ZZe5uqcaBLabWxdmbBLlqw/0f7aV60DesrNw4MiLa@Lq@2VXBNNdsL@QN9V0Kze6y7vEf4tJnmkufrakDvTG4i1SBPvDTvJjs05aWl@9bA6SWjz@YgEWPyt8zq/4v)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/7oaq5)

Installation on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install mksh`.

mksh [does not interpret](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh_old.htm) numbers beginning with `0` as octal, which provides separation from oksh (#354):

```sh
echo $((346+010))
```

Comment: These shells aren't in the helper list at the top of the script which caught me off-guard as I was going to look at adding some in, but you've done them already!

Answer (score 2):

## 362. Befunge-93 ([CCBI](https://github.com/Deewiant/CCBI)), 16036 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e  xx xx    xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_xxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  xxxxxxxxxxxx r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8;s0::&&1Pr"93"pllasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrlop#astd[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML ma5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NYdiD4saPg@RFXoCpJigRAgG9SpFKpVFaqKrOUnVJWlYtkMkESJJECASZASmRKyuju2e11255ZT097ot32uNo969n2eiLGO7Gzbu/YMxH2fpxwzCf/gPRjY8Ox4f4HveecC4CgREqZ7XHExMZCInCf55577rnnnvvAQUf3hj/7WQwv9sSx5gPLmbCJ4U1YzzVPDVdm9@bsrm56eS0rCJhq1x1MR4Y98SpCjKmMWbo9mOoDg/VNa2K4aeYZBusYlnMG8Rpj21N76hm9OviyjNnGGTuwu2YPILCJc2LY5mvDhbgcY/cN62J0MWFdZzTS7Z7Hxq5pTyg2z9gTHTz9afeE6R1v4urdienYEFVg7Jlt6aNOT2eUfOwaPFORAajuCeVZjikx9thxPQNKcLqG5zkYWIZA3TWdR7uffnQlvZphH@mA1NgyZleKV1X2uWm4vas5NPbZ8YMHV0Oz7BPJsdmD6yipObY7nTgHk6vw82x3YNg60@SyrF2NLAAxJ4ZVypQyV6OK0J7GxOwulQMRD0wXWlf3W5F1dRtaC9tyixmj8WTOJN7@umWFbesx3WNTb6pblM6ejjqGGyT0Jro7Me0BOzMnQzYZml6Yj1J7Y71rSD3DMkfmxOgxy4RMTt@HAqDtHjsx5meOC03uw3Rsaw4Zja7ZNzFLgAcAxCsxGRoczkifQyPbE2AOpjMP0LCMAFpSiEH6@0ZnOmDOdDKeThjg1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadaBOCAyhZ8NDdtnZgAnA4hjh2P1ckqoGQue13s9lgE@BjxODGYC1QitCstmIZw5LlANUgUY@cCIr3kdjRm0GTRR36mwfCYD8fthCGKrW57jI7OMGkba0FepzRDuE9cZuPoIqNEziKafHTxhXtdxwQc/TMv7001guvqEbW@z@P6n9@OsHjaL7HaEsIlq7ByaIBZEslPdmgKHRFvCgfZxw9wCNll8I15hcSCLlmG5HMtBty0xLQ9EUjNlcED/17Iq/ApMK7GcCj0oH09jOX1XH5iWwaEMEEoRGV/LMw3umRzLqiWecuBYfZ6sS4UVWbbECkVWzLMi3MusrEFpCDrH1HIefgX4AbQyoKLCL5vjgBZ8D3yKvLbH@vrItOY@dALfZXmVFQEi4KsCZK0EEOCZzeIvCz9Ca/mKwp4MgdpD/RTAS5Z5gtLICAUSNqECD2VrSyGJiCKXF@8NsXggHRAtX2JFKL4AlMgBCkBZrQTF5zO8It7QsCw/29DDbIRtMQM/wLwIdCgB9TNAywwSswg/8IO800CwaSDFNBBMGggTTQN3FouAdAWIK0BTFnx6DXXvBAri5Wg9Ij5IdACjIrVRiKlIJIAArcWy0GYFlgNGyCIj5LMM8AdcigUGcqykslKOlYoM6FnOMGgbFfBCLlFBfqqAj4rAoP1VYAAVcFKB2ioAVbN5JkSIrWYxHvJmIS@QRs1Bnhy4oeHUAv4gH3CGCkWqUKamlRdMCLhpeahvPkvcqRWgdYsQB3TTAFcN2EkDbLUSxGPeEtCwhMxbjKc5IXSkA7QKsjvwIRAjD/gQXEgLbq2Y5fTTrfFQ76C05jk7fcxawG5QQDJC1gxWD545pCagkgEw2AsAfQ04IAvkyELTZnNY/KUAHZgP11HxB1Lic@z6KMxQYIOwckgUL3gyYQfiJgnScVlygiizgDdhuOjqKNawkxskpAI45kRmUAiMrYZziroASZqlYjySRh0Xh34YOnqG6zJMC/qClya55U07nvFqioPTAq8@CEID5GVfN60QAeqc@oSkKjzjHpQ3X0a77zoj6sEjlEuW44zXjAEgBc8Q0EPnzFigvhCS@nhswVAE4QYfCQGZM52UGNJ4oqVyhCAT5usOTQBIRYEIN12jS7T3qw65syDsl1GsMK1@J4tQ7kXGqCwbOyC/PcxjTy2rAoOH0WXZutIzThUM4ePY8viFOAQjG4xPPoiODgoIYk5YhJDuaDKNmcdBy3rOaLlqXGgdhFUfmjjaWGf6HFqvD/LKmOkjUJMY6iI2jJAj4BjegtgSoAhitQ5Yz7HjkxDKmQuaAVQ6rAlpH0iTiTkyQKV0IAu2eI6QRpFJmHXmwMpErZxMOiTH5AqhZOEqoXhALhLAOwuMob1pF6mGZZs2cRCMPR4qTq6h93iYMHFZs6nDz4VBcuyrzTI6MOERohbRumCENYD6vjrTJYg48Bu2B7qaJzMTlVrg/IHTB2Y7M6HuoC5B1gXsLhEBSRAGzeSuLBDJkYFGJxYzWXc8ZhAOSgiw54NMCcZ156XJXkOkNQS9rDt13TmbjaElzBGkmnSdfh@497UxHgIINuqx7rwL3RMaGblH6Dkkkbrj5WoufJsGpLFR09t78otsYADZQQvoo8qPLL@owHhMVSBS6DbXEGwdKIVV6I7nRBYAE@boO46M4T3H8IhZHPck7PpYmGcMqGtAP@svhNEINR7gUps0tR5IHr97IXwsUFhZGSzK54KPDBu6The4Ejo9NB@26S7rw8wloheg8qZ3u8Z44vOJQ@LMtCNK1OEDVKIoVPKByd5Q2LzLtq9wDSQNOSeiIKBSiaiPfd1OR1nrT49AZbCNhR7PJYs1v1Y8pDi9Urr4AtMsYfBCXIPDmLoEapQkJKYTFCUoHc3uEGXhBKUNKTHQ29zp9epDWLR4d8Skflg2YqOC2BFkJQxCPNbDkOBnXQckjy2EVV8KwKRLAbeA1r3RCshOiKTVi4bKii6DULwN6MixnRVQgZghXEyyHENtQcx4hFJDt0JmpO7iLbURCuzFjB0HMhhDx2PHhZ7Bhc6cpmfUZBHu8mc1iXCsSMJsf3lohSEjjgP@BEdByDC2YC5HXQx7KqirOkgKEGJ81gEyz@ElRhCmXk@wfPzOSPRzZoKx1LYN1Hh1d86BQPVgeIaC5sx0XRCDpzhI8DEoGExk4lMYE2D@hZIVyUH9/mrhMnL03rRjzq5ObboYKL/0hFPdZX2c1bigdEAnSsT7XjxZpXDKGYkSFWc8USgrv4uQkBLJ0OSJPkyUYJB4AILmaG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ7MyHU09rE@nlzF7iWEIdOMTqBfk6/KBjB8SxLcJQwjTDBCkTFCd0HPgE4Iqnu53Ovo7AKkB0zRZ3uUG5VMeqpyLizLsHthWT4hEJdofWVehOd2ySFFRjWsASanmtMgsUTAd6QEZRQhQFH8sRUDSNvjcaTX8MCpTYsbLMFVkSQ7D5V9GAAShIwJyofZNSdtX125cydQXDZqNWA20KZAbPaS0WlCsAokg6SGxDJpI34h8sQ5mmDfSCShvpj4kmMDahNwaq3OzidDF3oc@S8FSARkFWzk5ICwfjt/ap5Me1cb2sZATCRirwOlyexOxKoAgz/vDbWbqBpfoipMJeJIVWRezE@grzEvhWKDin4y1/BQ/a35qERaOIEY@Ly6kkQ8qx@2YOi9edfyVQLugs7OpVEH0D/xVwdCQZT2dYKg017rqRwIdgcOhz3ZPX5Y8/sij1Q6pl1ZCrCcrm5R8CYmF4O8jw7uPd19@ovtFTAss1O5GqCYuVIBh9rpTBrYUyUna5XNKIwF4Pvtm2FjxuU0ouBHM8mZRVSleRcGl1lAzsOnn1wlCWhCSA4qAdz4u6LS8DSgdAkd3RteGYTZIJWCIsMsQVomHbAAZuhA1DFeD/B5Mn39GhvvKlJjPxwxs6Y6BxAEKgd2kE/GyCsKWBDV6fMRkfKCFmrauHq7cEVTBvh8hFrzVWRIlY6wzEeHD/af1gisv1ghURLFm4Aupbs9GXjemvYMYVUaEH/g6rKUvEAc9WnCdSWBu90lAi/alq2BDwBwriM7TLJGQdW8IeC@d7VuFCp1Qw4gP0G4qldG9aHu@yIawQOHuC5OeVeNohSxGKzCoJUjVhi7PGx183mjmCtHh63uosxeFCittMI4EOiNLkSdeBKGyAst0lerffSPHl1D3CMlEqYCUoCZZzGZyvIsAWcvksninrIHMzTHMuTPSeKJTEwqSjxYbJW7Hk0@I@n3Z@YkkUnyp5qEtFD67u6Bdj9I7K8D0koGTRpwLo4jk9vHTZOuBzxiO5YzcNgW5OHaYVAgqE1rq7k7cOxrLaRjIFY1hvsuIH9x4UYfw1hjvqaJI@WKTlf5Do5ue2cgpdVCFolEFCJQCqWXX@qnOpBrUe@jgy/3YRBR85lM6M7QBSSI5CFyoasbCaUAJkFBso/PygqGezDXensQIUU2QbDSvqALM@4uolcGksSUlZXpV6L0sXON4i@d@RXWghDOWuCIkOzg0yePDj7df7z7RXOi5fNL/lymXADCQXkd0IXkIacb9tYt3jWxWgguBn3Dxe4FUmAKE5RgCX7quSC4ZUwicwTWcA3fvUp87AztuJe8WpkzjJVe2l3OQo@x8/GkfkaYaPcsnIy4fAsQx3Pkn@FkMvYqigK9fDjtyDBpVV52HUsfKJQPBgbLUlScuhwc4rqGtyoHIOPNDZ6DL26B6jCnFUTdGjkweaGNRBQNLMHB06qVZQ6GMBfG3UbDTcohB1NtlB7MEGCurIR1IwFMPqCt/wzaSeSs/YGqlThfqxktp4hBsqXuD2k3@gZMnRIwWgEpkle8rHmneYfNQUojpKtAYkzeokUOj@FYYDFQJGnVFOf5AXFIWuB6KcoKotGrKa7mgpRS8plcUS3kFZiWwTQNdFYJ19ykkT7pDqWJIwE8yenTukGEC/teV7f78pbvCJAFve9DqGq28bzZtFugoDfvEG64mdeYtxpqK1ll17Ns@emTVeDepeoh7wYBwLvkBNakJ1sjz3r6dXHW06l39ZgyGY39MUcas8e7oEi9dkBe94xo38MMSjRS2VpKq2DiN8qKBSELswp4Q0op0KFgpAXWUxAvCZReVA@Bc0BuRTKwxWoGrwffNI/IEZx0I9@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@yT4GNQCLjfp0GWiADTe9TmXaOKc9ObKTKquTBpNFDFTLjxZiPTbDXPm71U8zKextzJql6D@SEIr0liJA9cZzoGxa2Rq0gg25KNbKVV7dTimfhWIlGSLChITyY/LCVTOqd1Im4ATyWazTiQ1KdOozt0Cd4srSWTIaEAj74JswzLSsTl8xKU30m2kqk45E3G0yCWa/E40KWLRPCo0rgiwJnogTkDUkLHhCEuuqdAApI2p7C7fmmMh3M3miBcdQMtG1fQFwcA8JwESvGolHzN80cVuqWZfqD38nSg3OLiHepL4zmX7gLHtKksHTcJxt1TqT9yJrrymQyTJjkyXMY34ookwUhIMRwSVfux6WEX1m3DmXrRlcaVC6BYOoQeD6cgLIMzP2ngKnMsGN2hw@KbdwE6C/d7cCjBrSuJb4AFAHpdGX4oRFErwc0S0C7olIYJcpHOt9CqjEpIcNETrM3nC@NXclhalfKwDBZkDmzHNSQgCeQQ6EgKHXQS6sw/FXNAK1/X9iX8WBrScOJtGiARH1iOTrTl4jqyHzQeRfLD/ByyPDV6ggXyow/iUeZt4Ro9ZUugXVrHHcIIAbVBSayFrTXyIxTHG/fkyQyyCgkccKORfHYHSucZ62maVujm@5UgDrkCiD2ERsJZqQ1T3CBKUiEy6TfyPl8WCubonx7e3@drJzTY4vCK62jtkdObgl7pz5ueGvYgzfaBn0zbGZlAhiD/6xPrqeNM@CwfPOtWZvik2RxNLZ3WfK4uy9yYr@t0HIuWgm7Kukg/dT3d0vkiVBC7@9lj0PWfHR/V5EokkaKfjm4sG9chVxfL6XkQ3XOk/dZge8jjjClu5kUct4KjdChm/IgCRkz9g3TQRkF4EcODLoV7KH54CcNHeIgOdGV/FYG8YaCfsEwJ8WAdniLyA8/VzCWGr52DhelUSscVxwW256pG4aeTfn8pOEvBJxKKJmsRnKNgfsBuaY4YRSnPE@Fpu6U0UUAFShMeulubrkjpxnQCTw53Fh@HhxCGhhVsLT4FjQW3z2DQt1CvgkkLquj8YJwBGvYYd0lIdOPeG@uCEupdW8@AzjaWeGohtkEdCAY3BVUaYVNh/tp3lbqQ7fh7lh4Xqw7M@WlZZbvOd7lxTuXy6ZzCV@U32wBiu14NTjGtS4YlxeNhMoJKuEEOqiZt7F@ranhMw6PFdoGyVAVPgenETMtIzVlxv3URVzwiQ5@Jzebsw4z2BcxL8Aja5h1lYFSxwHX0qgYxcV@H7cyZBBofpuIL190hyBmWmi2TEtpnavcdqyfxXTJgGMbnV9hA/iGF8GicfwLSMN3gVBwdS@RZUb5GDtRdg3ulSevXE0SO4IWAoPucs4uT9OkFa8CQdyp7Y8uctNilPHHaQyTJZOraVw/rcR3UdfW5J/hnXGps9@lHnzUyLQ5BGOm481XirTgLznyC4gyKEh7OBRee1JmYE9IE6CSCifVVZUBqRpskgD7A4AVUWViQXyNE/cK4WNSlb8BMNWEg5t58lGZG8lLuW/pkYtic5/j243py830iv5gaFb/jbzpUWIZ2ZkAzNTEOUKyyo@P7@0@fysC5XiK@jzs4FeiOencICsq6SgeUjFa@wj7sxdmHmCeJ03YBuhrMPtp@fmDqKjA9zD@gdJQdA8NNQGASN1@6EEz7XZSRa2g@gfC8VXdCNAqBJYwk1ImAVVbi/8zmUy0fzwpwfIooCeRO3KkAbc2kPLXNV7IHAw3prZAkzierMF7UNhMkxTbVJHGPa45w6xhmWKQ0Qg0aDSa9BikHiUXWalX5GQBIixMwd4DUFUVqCjoaXFODpq9BMKg0BMHPXnvDnjcyUrmV2lwFig6X@ad6ef0jcBHCMmjPWFnsZoL6@7WOzHHge4Fccj@j6fSVI@0VtskdIl9zpuTBgSkSOnS@avmc1PIpLOhkKEpoKQYrEoiEmH/m2udZiifJD3MezEYBiSQ7D4muIcnZxQXRkG1qjGgILpXxxrgMZp8gmB45UJtH/nnrqHZAvdU/SIJ9timIwTRreacWY7gKr5xe0U6lUzGaj2uHpn3i0H5P6GpnZDWPGmGYe3RiXc/ZN70h3ZaShjjwtNo67LxRp0@3FQlo28PfUKcAWlD3dWFQInXlKT1obX1FycuHSJaK7Rj9qT2g3Ud0M@nVLSmlcokS9zsdc11SIAKeCwueK5KBkEJ@1uScrAYHuHEpBsYjEFx89rKo@tXzR2yJ7jA6TCCX//zP3@gB/a@3zhAGClx5DB1tGLqxpaT@2sbys6KHbqsbli@QTy1TJ8KQ6zaQXd2FKulW6FgNmjbhJQmG/xFuKfgtDryJN9Aab2AzjjnfEQyeqwtZtalmg8jsrkt75TwWL4q2f2Bi1yMicCXINCgTiS7eCMaMb8FEptgoxm5HKjg0xYiZebsPp5Mpv4PiemsjmmP83dQ3/ZSZvN5RDZg66h3TuKHJXf1k2nOk8ckg1FMLK9Iuak97wBKoA/52cBudq6vPK@iaAxhng@e6ZIuhTTmjx21c4dlTbyx1aBbe4z7qCKMbSnAtfl@XxPTfiAod66lmWnR7R070oQOj@KchFDxrKkWIZl4hs6V35qiDDN@fy8KTBSBxat1UKpNds7U8Hq/PjzNJyl8ur849k7ucHqvWCBR@nlXiq2hUYf@E6y2tCsOVOdItSetFnGuF@aqDCdeShnualMc4xR2d05Utt6A@DkjdqaW7C9cNLL7AI9hGWLci7Q8bT8yuA@rAmKlFWdWCoSMyYJDIDI7GLQrC48R0ixx/MFeRsQfTQhzEpdC1WgQ43QkeGV3DU@8g0PhRTTwQG2ES2VlHqa5zhr@16sMQpqb8vnpEe70Sq3cQTpLVtXQYx9cOB0uLg7j4eAujnpmeQbfVhD1Zieika60MX@4CwbJfdBnvNrb2TMvx2BHdbyLQwAUq8Ptqho7S0tRtiRbDo@4bZFBwxmHRoLo1cKxCaaDocFvb6lO3j3Lff76rhAsllKreIqEC9cexVf@5Vq6fKO7JbQ1Eb4G5eL414rxhiF0lpvy9l/W1g4kBbtytrtmDTIlyygpf6ltTMG65nOnz4PlzDB3rSBsMHeM5qdOg3WGGcgkcE5er2D9PabmbS@u9m1C6BrZ4WyUijXtiGTBY0f1akzIto75nDjWTeXcR1bemxtRYOdE47Lw08F3lGyYZ745Uxq/Gpr9Sj5sD@GpKmOq1PzN8J6xxnEbfjcJEt8yucbsqsyzUxqB9j3Hq/AQcT9BxPcfAno6XWnVpdmY/vZlkw3HQpZ3eEnYY875yqHSLprSkn3sG/W6cMfEZHh4Qq@UymYyvwER2XJY8N82ksmHelya/LxVMIYuSF2lxl82NOFeXQWSJHkFcK4K0dRN7SlwuK7ZpG5M53t9RmnYcx3qflgKh2jNRFQPNko7a3tRi19Qd/yUStli68HDBo9Nft2jBRxt/bgn0wUnzTY0e3RJ6p9aUcNNzhBtSy96bl28iG0y3lYIvc@OaED98a63XJf3VEFUuycUbex3XUJ2OYen8MSvkboJXlrM3wlsWGv5mLW7u8i3dxVZ87IpQGs@BWGYPZilDY2SQ9wYtX@@h3QH/sTbRzMHfuuiZYXSV2b7RXZdgbIJcsPG@tIccUZYmjg3zqwme88N5ioUnSf3QdRI42PVbSeSDkT4wuCGMmyTlYsECT9Pwad3CuXrposJP0HQh28LCwXqWgE51Ysy94LkS4ON5F9p1Orp9ue1K5@/iGug79PZ1R1ivD7H20BnaQ2PIz42HvnWdA/hxwg2X3IQ6YD0Y4lG28XjpiHuUnpZjWe9CTxSNXFA6Tn8lTvv48iu@ufVecOd6ByL8x62Ld/qEyw50rO01Q2MK45LnTJyxIZFvXVILF3r4fZ0MDTapf94VpBvn@UCR4Pnzwr91bjnQncl4TI/22Jp6dKOsEr2zfJve1OdHU@hQpOMO5NfOqCP7gbJ/boW2wFeLmI456Q7xpXHO2cbA6XSH5m1Idwx9YpsnSrDkw73vNHdFyphMuo/BsmUCed25jPxSi8Yf4eNgXaP7q0d8WAsdN@grq1bo6LVsaayfdD2@GoouVsEF4Uhv5C9vV@j198qrqTlZAI2cZQqXd/m2BDrW4e6fnlirWdE7Egsx7J@qWMulpKSjQi4ZGVB41HXFLp9zi3SxbJbf1iEUrSVhFDmX8j7k9s/@0OqgGVm3hfAl/lo6tLRykLOH04F3XWDy5foeqGh4W79sQWeZI0vWMGbptv9YR2bNUvAlR3i2QeeaGjfuqeRv3FShdKol6Y4JjzY8oOmma9fQLHPs8TuT@mu34vyzTDAXv7pfyGkzXz2Z9humZ/T5Fgi6blMRR46LJ5FBB5G6uJOOK@gozLnixQWX7QxAqEsWWyQO0q5TW1YeE1rd/OGYKX3xqTHQ8az1I3OChzVXcAWx7KrjRbfC/vpU98yvT6Fm65gNLTbwbUg3@mo/@lbAe6wPzO7DpYYIkfQJ7J/05I8l9seg621xNjQ9PNEUOm5YmEKW40yMXNeGecOKlFfX7UNjFYsOxF@DXJl61dq6M57j22Jzct20rG5OaJXVf66bOq47BHYjEmfT0Xjq@Y/VONCZqegq9OiEwr0zE4BLr0C0sqFuTVavVEeWXEEL8wfFhXOdNv6laTkD9mUpw0BpAyUMlfMVjHMPhucneCDHtVdwIpX9jtueuNAhubxir6BtjSyTTNuc3LyaM5ng4ZzgiZXhIwe@oaA8wrt8930hSMerKfLodl1/8WryLeM7cN6RM3W7BjpDeyPRaYFfqrEXnD7GNzoctJdyFp2ldR0Luhc4rJVdpuvY04nkTu0bR4XCjaNChc1KhQgbsMTX9x8/S0a5gU5r36aFGjD5m3rWfOFae2DgCpOZNihi6@XocupgLnGf20l6SkeFb8mzi8acuiSu7zur5jtP5jCAvPOECYT/dHTf6OK24a1lf@o8dmwHRqMxCMrRU4O/87900GN1Rsz2CN9qB/r0bi3miMCuGYS4tqGPjQ60r7VwvctYxAHf1yf6mqGI1gZp/he6buUV0@oY7kta9Iu4101plxF6aMxobrGeYXgflCbdLleJcT1uqY8s7dh4Y8ex@Z2kbQYe6uObpQoMBXR7941yGQ/iL60LrJyfLVf18JSfEjF63CjFurq6Rsex@P2GM0m2yc8E6K5peMojtHFAYYUck0D78m6UIcUbZchiagSa7Knu0Sb96qnGAqQ6e48jQEPd7Tq4E@Y7bjidEzFMcIuYDs/284MDHSD8DCSW3p36FhhvQ8sadUZ0WzthiLTmU6ODbwV1yJrHRJ9db0y@MuSbMoic6AoNAATiCjt1gSWewGwkefuwtTSPWqaqOaYbSeq12@V0WEeyTaP7WsdVM4fotVibXoqHOiufknPNWnWkG9EqsqLTm@4re9Ly0TVQaCxDmgxdmPMrk5uWtwMzKyv2Q6YjAzeZl3dh1qqujjekyjqr99ND4eoakm/rD2RJaPeP64fS7lrNE8HD/@G9jxUYhNuFXGB6BETX7Tv4gPzUtf3Hu3DgE8eb9M3ZIeCNbwGsEydYrTxkgQfvGejaWlcJaD17avHVh0Hk3NWoR9MxiUzbSpJF4npiSIZ9KpEhuNn1Gjn8pS9lF02iToye5NtBwJ0G6VHw/leYzH@u2ECNykY87KkqnLCzQs4//rmKuGeBZAB9y5lIY4@eyth7cvDo8Fgee@rK8Wl3iG9HXNPjlgwraKVMZEnqpe5G9jv5cbSe6U2Ue0eqtPfoQMYEa@jNdzQkeODO3NJj7bqnb29UV/S1syCMNSarFcSHx48fpRavaLLE3tB1RkYyGr13dJTGN00@PloZHc39AHpH35mtzX6wr6rJFez7zKbdwXXSc0VJ6yAdGzAbBWZ8yO2y3KpcdZ2x0Tuej43PYPBECe69Y/GFtZX8VD81B9gLWXktoaijsrJcyCUjJ7Nhsm244XNde56YY5SWXXoo/LH2OApqDlnFza7WHm7a8b@qxbCMfxLh/TKpmevcOjEl6BmDIboU3fv7Iqaq6jo6H@l9aFeWX9tYywlW7Q9bzuk7bCUb/uRFCoOkCXCVZN56jrwojUB0K3jD5Xk/EJydtcdgbgIQBhdWdvgzw57rtkR7WTepFxXIjYfabkzypfEOG1LhCZ9TtAC9co8vPFLPEl1yJm8p@NiNZNnbu3dwW4anPi1vTvXRp8/YE91DIyQ3J4xibLwDxgvN6KWE61ZoAW/tdmrPBVDajfAG49X9ucKOdLfn2PPZ7Ztw9A4qDu1kXDiEhT5KZFjmzFw1VnX5utaT1ceMbiubv8ThzJf04KhxGh/Q22//M1XNZMj0ED7VDPfe0jJBB2cJdOlztGcXjTo@CEVDF/UWGQKSK2ejj4wZHkfhq8GrJvUrx7fCDWNfMbl@OLkprnRDXO6G8q7FYSDLyhn1BoD5G@JYXg6jHznW2dCR93TX8FacP16J0E0VKd9QkXJEOr8uZXARlDYWffd6FR9fXfAfK7n12Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lXXY7aORSfYYjaVfj/ePU@guHW8ZOP4rH9y/uryzqbGyoMf669URJGlOVkaBEDSGU3ol4nr08gZpB3Rewx6Y3L4iu@dM9sl3w8QsfON59VkEc3x/Ol6PMchGtPN/VZwvJfwc5szOmcfu4atxCzV9xdwfz8etDl@n07JwYRDNjD483g246/BI0SIlLrD44slSML48Ojk8ioS5xmy2btIrzdbNIVfGLEr99Di3VOx2/fnpCmKtf98I1A2Qx@FzrR7Ehd3HR9dFAk7fhpORFcR8rNuLFdOlBus5E3rTcGXkk/mMjlGubOkhP8W2Ks7trghemtjDgGyaULantNtoWb/dXseVx8YXtPcAahCbcLWEA/UNLxmz3DDAkLKs7ajOyUL5WUL3aDw07dnKqNG6PHSKNPHSW90NdtmR5ZyxR6FVoXXiQVsNXD817HXCadXLilI5e7MWlr2iUi2A8vdRoTpRW@Ze2rdGw9/f5m/NenJgcD6RsFOpZHL5kynRV4DR4m9iEy1ebtLrvpD24oJt@K/YQoQYvLTrv1SMhvFgym/gW8ECgZjUNqGYWk3Nl9kOfqOkAgp9kkrEIDI/FpTVYJvn/vuylYp6yTZqTKyIzH9jObQmzC3iAly05Ql1YtKJyjYnELMZvG3L6OMO7ILRIgHMStR8BnyyErU7UPXfRwaUNs@fHDzZPzrePX521Mi0Lv33lYNK2DaUFlhF@DDbE6HuPtlA@eD2sek9eQuKow9P4OKCF9SLQc2uVK22VLVFpcQdzLN5btuKQq9sK9Il4CeJvDSKxS4EQRx2UGNqH/9t/Qp/e5peAocm4qBFKhParMIyqwoe6zCQbtp@/NUP6lAsfnCpgp9cwoJ9k8bAiAPH6fklega7/QpKfLB78OjZ030WILhgmjOzNxnWynlu8ZqbkYB26pt0hq3G4n6WOLRVrRZ/EAfCxOU4q9BL9mRtGvgckgXUwdfz/dxbLLFJ8IGC8bBRlP/8DeUyLuNx7CSkjQdIxaFYYHlilI2NDXYMTMLuPz34bP8pQ/z371MwkghBsGN8w/fPftzj32sILPAEH5tyRzTqkQUTIfqWf/Dq@@LtfKQ5dd3x@k9O0fcR6B348MMM4ZdlBIG@2wF8e0bG864YVkuSrSP@iSzf7l1QELFQYOMdV/7Rhp3rsVPTM/ENfMShjybllpkdDwuRGUWZ7eL3tPCrXTp9PARQn9oTbrbJN94SA06TQ5GTZpuELP/UiBhJGN/eAGbvGKAQMc82YXidVNhL4ERcXa9wCw2SVI9fyxKArpBLwkE0kvCaDTpPabrK21/7J8qgysA9Afd3fPcscw98v@L7@uD@Ve5@riCjXbdZt8AlihDamfRrwBEJ6Y@0j3xGzOZWMRaEQ9N6gVxl5gia6ZSojsl5CfwugThewEk0PoNGA3aDFvOtYfDyDLeVQEOXFUVBlkIlXaZ3EYwZPxh4xeBlIV/IqQogKZ0GAMlC/QDfeOYAk8kKdBPh1BzXXoDit729zUScqRu1QpW3rLJpP8@KL0JENyGtcDZE5BoM8kCWRQ6Iq/vZYPBJqUnMitIrrsZRcPUcGJUoHkcv9Ns@IUSWAGJxGhlo8nyGX5ybuPPAcGsHv9EW@XrJpg9IUmFMIldSFHw7Ep86E2Af6KSL7xNxOxJ4MJaPgGgR0ePfYSR7qciP8vWetXj9OfhMit/XZJQBHFQ2c3Uwjbat@DmCOEIQFXEV@zaes@akabcUzpsM2PSHK5jZBvcvK4M1PMvrvXvdWmbiqq1LJBa7e2Q7uCTxACrDEpqiZRW1kFxUKZdbWSW/Rn4xUB00yXMBxYGYApHRNcyXztjb3ds/@PjwydE1i5CUMn41Gcj9@naqKcnpRit0xKPVWm6Sew@Uo8f3HgQNsUC6EJHGIPj9mqg31WSx0oggF2@uXK3aKgyv1m49xp/zd9uv4pvVbkKNMl3DQ828R7l0elx6QO@AXS1cK62iVj5/E0oLeEoE9B5/gfcaqonk@WWjtV1v2rH4dU5Y0RGex@Qt7ATganpbmwoy@/XKYcXCL6Qe42fSvGhfzK7ui@JmFg2Oof2AiXOyMMnmB0QiIvUNigERKchKkHRt7zvkOvrCcKDGv@DKLZVF7TBFEC5kbqJ4BNRx8DFYlCILs6e@xc8hTGUtsyME9q@45c/AQGFo9JPbrkokBf/jGbzghP952FllJtNRsUQSpR3BSrObjIgG8JICdGjU7p5MYbb2xBlzY@p0JOC@EbieOiB@70/5EoLBPp6OIF2fHk8N2p4ByS1BZqBkPESV61IgJXwborMUWmmF8hpoSdSvuDzq5ROzpDw0Zj1zALI9kUyDRPtQVVsstDOKlSa7onZcpDZbtMKNXfEjfC07Svb3MjY7WyCgN3TZtHvGLBE/iycrLSgfw@Nnn5/Gk@IqXiKjt74V2N5V67ch@kX1ZkmiT/zeGZiWXSUtyuXrUgLCrgLmVtiCLzmVy/LQE@jLfDXU3I8m7iNwghqR6I/0MUtMbW7BTmbkTTQTdppMe0l1bh3TZqkUTajgQREyo5x9cvHxO6Hbc5ZQasAEGOrZPXy8NsesocpyC9xUSJJt4hfW9kDjQpuOSQHmwJClQmBryEIwzQCMeCeROYNDHoyHtPAgO4AroumDU7SK7SBNqNasfodFvpi3rDmK5XLFb9BlqVhmwH3XxaGsANhrci7Q64G6vnEboBlMf2UhthDk1yVejMqNcUQe@lZxAJ1YxKJtYCyHAayFvdnu0MVfYt@GvgL6QaXy7PhBu5RURBZa1xm4Zg93WbhR9nCK539GB7qpspQ0XuUzuo8wG9oxbHPzPWhO7wF1GPGKSI1FyXD1o9cL3lTVG7nez@i3AqTM4QDgv4XYDsCh7clgWWxF3Gph/7Of4We1xcSmqp603dNUPJ@pwk2t5lmefbjZlKTNRqZ2d1OHWdTk1awJc3JlK3f/1Bj2ewcDpSmKLMtyirJ1fh5/sPXEfK4VXs0us2rp1clYLTTkV7OWWKqlT1rsyZMv3rTfJMXZ6fyV2Exo9HnnvcMLUc3hRD9WKbPznUI2dlLGr6QyXc@fsBnMW9kJew3XSZ/hP7lf9yJuHd2d/mv6ulRcZLFmE7@JLRZFRWnEW/BP0/0XcPGJf6Mu1@Wd1ps3yYauT2ZzZprm2Ov14OcMQYPUkkcMyr0Dkp7SK6xJT5pA0TWa9RfrCHoebnUNX0mV77YxhExiznaNwWC6r8/N6YPJ4y8/D65neL1@umJBopVKJSSpcTW40tbzMaZltD/7ycZl@vxJe/vPvjlSjA18HOLjO5eP0X2k5j/c2Pjw3r1cLq1pGnc/@fLJL@7u7ubup/NPGvmdnJTZ2P7TP9nY0LRtTdloeZ7aijdOTr4QtUxOlP/sR/H2kydf97x69v/8xpu6irci3E5ZEeQEXFmmghPvJfipqGO96xV7HQMuV2Nz@mvHgvDzDabWd4r/5XuHr2KTWF1TPnfhOYm9ihVKMe4EB/iyge80Vo9tY7LCZWyu1Go1cBb/y7@F/PWPAQ7GzLfhVs8HsArzWF2qUZaLWL0ADlXToNz/@xvfiGDIxUSN1LjgussacIm5oibutODaomtbQKuFUkZRgnT2ZDgxHKaW7qh30GOCBx62gebfjUkzht8cZod3GXvaSKVSLbktwSU/xzUiRVW1pqreAWkgfbhVq0lbjJtlzGbzd9C0dJJWtAYODJjGHfb5P8QVWxVY/bnBPRVihY27L@7X61CpbD27VU/R5fck6lTFkug4d0WWZi/iMAVptF484j2H1cVMSRPT6TTvTjMklTRbcBJe/B6LhSHYZdnVsKUskMQPjb1/utg@Xn/@v/359//8e/T3ffr9BzTraPfMvrIFiU6hS9ThulupdOt1se6K503014GPMpVSpaS0L5uJLZBAradMzXx0Ec9n40f49WocAFgzSbnhomLrfvHor8cWwXUeUo@G@RE8MQUwvxbkWKIauUOqXUsHQ6t/AFZqnNZbEipENamhFvItieeqB1eZNe5CM4lasSy26lpeO2R32zN@seGmx5wYzAwLAR19fOuLutXDmIWvHg2K1YNs9UWa900X4ivEGg2lZdCAEISxuxuVjVKlUNGUdn39BawZ9VJSwzCeeLHTWHhxysYWBI2FrHk1LGiK0MMCDmbvkw40I@ggM/zHnhJeESf6qJWyBVWs@i6tzcQqMImWlbRBW8yoIvY2Sovr@3BtwB/9wxV68b5BIX4wJbl@bbCKuqVllfyHhX2Nvd8lwDjBup1O53W3g2qA3tG7ujrRp/pMn@uTzrQz60y60y5@b36pmszNOnmn5PiVZ7IUy@bVzdgdYuo3jQ32lEuhFksFVzN16/VMltu@kxwO/iTJmcWE2D/AVVc1lW3B@JSBGyhl5IQ5M/6pqsBi53C13mw13mxBB62ntkk6tuqSjyU85PbdVkq6vGyAu1r1/7frobNKF3dB5VqXqdT28zqoHs/rjRSAfO6DlCVGQOV2vbVNMWFhfml@9HYLlBcptd3Yrjl79JOpg0jxnBMvOHdbAHh7Cdm7d1MyuO4CgPom9MdkKrUpSRs4Njb8sQISt@qpoFaIQwK0hfPzn/MHEz3oxZfbl/XLxvbl5fY2/G/T/dJ/Qujl9rV/eiyuNWkW8S0ULc2GUm8qTV9YtMAvK3UMkZUmOOrwhHSNrFZqNdABl9z6b/NfTi/uYQii3JIBayG2xbZiaGQwG9sSYi/efvW/4K/59qvfR32RwZ9REWLn2K2VLZxtlvmkE27Mfmyzx/yywY2/wIshGPC4joE2v9m4IaUoL2RW4Wv@CbVUSMo4ALedfhvtFsjsBSRFxQ3kHBO1UkFsp9S5xmLbYqFIQu4Xrl3xePwfvdDKxThfnsHX7V94nvc4gtsCO0hc1TKqpF7UuUV5/vGPX1h1/aNfWHcJsYsyMypAla7HOD2EGLBPTFEkCcap@vYID2TjDomEk9HT2hfSs10JV0/0Ce1/dfnKQO1gv1Yu1/nmzuYT6ixb97fgrsL//gbUgzX7kLbZr3VHoPc2@9m81kT74zGp8wr/Hr3GP3bcxb@nr/CPHb/Gv6cT/GOPO/h3/Ar/djv4dzzCv3uv8O/xa/x7NsC/5teyWbUqbp4TaVJqWb3cnIlEompsp9782sSdVyzDbpi9lv9pnWyuzJKx5teMGX5gvcID@/Gffveb34zXanEpTh8syamOy9RkFagPNfLi1btxIVZjm@qmmrEy3YzaUTvgMFnGZZlhZqj2YHrSVlnGYJl5Zs4yI0ftgcuAvwy4zEyfZQYsY2dsSAix4Jq0MxN09eExgL8@AHLhz8TzhR0102VQkIWqGn3rEMGD66LdFBoszsQXBswwZVXOyAWzhV@IaYgvXjSVrZZWLjEZmUpuN1404y2xKaLVcK2cY525sdF8IcKAnBE582EIi3keTFurMaXZVDiZgAJExcvLdnv/0/vttoKDT/Oxc7j4PzwcRb03/o8OnceHzsiB/8PDQ@gwRj11NwVi@e7dGohp/7ETq1d3mhUS9oHAjynbO816VkJ3IQUyXMOw1HteC4jwrG80hfhZAmccZzjpqH5@Vj2tkvss8IKjXV0kCJJxh/@E6wwGtmAScgbX6Rk6yIfOs8@boYs7lM/PIOhzBtOt8B@mdVHvf4V/87@t/8fPWJIlGq1k4vxyO0FXEv@SyfPL80v/Xk8mEr4nsQ1/GAB@zHJ@WUcnJToHVyORbCUvL3kY3BPJbQ6wDsVs1ynvIh0MBrGwSCqW3xL/dZ9QtH8141XQdvmUOp@hfhQTq0xfnKZpNmeZTLLaCT6IgHvD@gUdWUhW6Wt4m52G2vrTH9FHL3aSlCifq1bVLcY9Wk6rVnOBr1iqVkuBZzORKF@/6pkdtQCzjlwumaxWwbMTgM2AF/I22JsUq7Em3Ft37vBCStrFRQAzmyukMmoGcwcl5aFYw9O7vsA9Pzik70WAqMnH8EMtXJQkMvS1GfyiWVysiHfuJPwvpe/sJu/c0cqZi4swZDyGIHUpqN3umW67jeHZiwuxLdLpl3Ie/JnSxYWaKafUeNJxE5/ip/CgqISksg@1OpVaBjGu5YoQ7SOQ394u5Or1Qg5CCqV4EnfSG4h@C/CNi/GqGDunOqilIpeAYhWDo6eCoC/joMDOL2PUoCyXTyZAkCZB87uM4Z@LMpcPN/l8EihzKfKUarnMkyZZrpAopcr@X20D5uKg2vA/1M@yqdxWcesuaLr4581WXSiTq@dGTb2snRsVXEu/rHb9jwqjzQXjzp1sGUhUylSbQrt9f/d4t92uiaKI6hHcMJCku4CmKNx4g2qeL7c4RSrVu9TMainPoD15GikOIwQrAdEVbSuvlpBIgtlHkypAEkElGm2wDUGjJ96EMqfcBgTCJAYK78HFeqzDBnixAS6JMpNZdDGL8Xi6d7thIodffmzopbx4hSFGeAl@L8xyFoVB/Mmj3b3947S2LbGY9mB3L60dPbsXU9GbX/gpOov@p/u79w@fQYYnj/Z3j/Y/Ovhs/9kTCPfY2eIKhL5/XzyjrhX@M/a58NJ9rRuGbkwNo302nZ69Yi9Ns21CY1pTqJQzcJlntKEuY31Rryr8uqanv3ypu2O62NsffvvtD/@7t7/z3be/8@23v/P9n371/W/D78fw@y5/fvfflPN4/@lX/@x33/7270Dgf4DfH8HvJz/96je@wX/k/2P4/adI2B/7v0g6/hMA1q/89Kvv/einX/3qD@D3L/3fD67/fu0nq3/f/9b6H@b73u/enOa7/xZ@v8dhBWm/@9s8DJ/X0v82T/erP3j7L/4d//9T/w@dv/P2X/wx3nzPP/3Bn/6nt9/895pW@tN//fZb33v7rW@@/dZ33n7rH2tvf@Nfq5no7Xfffv8P/uoPf@@v/vB/pP8f0/333uX/7Q/@6V/8r3/xv//FH/q/n8Dv34HrJ3/x76Gr/O0f/BD/v/cHf/tHP8T///lf/e0f/Prf/sr/RI7f5I7/51/@G37/61/7j3/zW9/5q598429@/Sd/85t/8Ff/x6/@X7/xH//6v//9v/4n38TA3/zJX/3Rr/zlN7/9l9/653/5za/W3L994/2rdwj/6h8g5N3xfBc471Kv9w356ufC5@9DjUUpwCfA3b/89jd@CRj8XzD29ts/xreV4Lfm/8eaSml@zH3/H3Bo1@uMMRlwwe/X3377u0ii/wFIBP8hvb4TepZiuOc7Cw@Q9bdWZPrln371z39EvphRqdNeDY7dJa2U2oL5zVa57I/f/jYOZPmlZWghAL@k76CEWor7Dsq2tz/8xtsf/eO3P/zNtz/8FRy8pVw5vZuW1Fv2wCBh/h3SYcLCu6TDhF9g@SlaWJNSX4CPfeFHfvHFF0L7QsHX4u5eQOgXFMQvxqPwtTk/KojDcHyPjl2wqNt3Znznph8alsxY48WLFu6yQhiWniLdYytQjfJZNkv5iM0Y383BcFzE3eILuYwvY88oeibgbfG/cM4EllqscONn/AInOfx8fhHcKeShmNQs3EMiXY1x7WiLh9DuMJWbKzOswWyWmsEkGBxQQgqi7oE6XqulMGON4wNejlq9xAiVVKoG9cbcPE@6XUIQs3sEBXLWUk9Ze6s24xlTCK8ekCMlYNBTUdXEVKl2Hwqsze4zhIXACeyLF7V6qTarI7g3nB6pWeoe4YTAaqlZ/Q34awQT8gmx@28AlVItlaqXsECsJG@edJs3Up4qR3VPsZTfBvDEQ/47dxn7UFRLYpsrjEgwnhrvqUVqTAjJIb6Z2vKrQ/@Bk35bRPANKsovhfH4HdJNd7i6igkAriTJsszgh9vuO@wuRM84qBQVC48Uh5AijiAOCAMYrg@lhBS1b4o8UH6stvXeFwLDymxubgqxupgVD2UinaIw96RCbzzgIUCcXlSYWCiLGGzQ6x8BLpC/SuVvxnE7Lc44YPZhiv/u3t1iH0I16bkIE5iUyjo5J8ahbKdSogbw605KeA7TEgH4lABdCPKsRtt3KSGdZkyuxTCOHR4e@khQwPOakAI217Iq@nETaTqdxiCHLKfldNp/yvSkANl3yBTrP@VNJC59K5ppWq4Ks6cqwyAWneqoMAXGwDdv3kCr0KmqygFMPpl/wErLlSgSArh1EMuaB68JabmywGfmTC3kGEvQEitcSZYUWIJtJQV@Fp8jEVyJuFYqxSkdUF9ObAXn7QoqsQMur8bqiGhw8SlhKZ8MIvcO2d7h48f7nx6PWy0mGPTta6M9dp2u4XkJjNv99D5/D0MrF5KxRgNBH1c0FDDCfiVDwvjg/tODowrjlfabIEGIVWk31a9mWRVi4/Hn2zH/vJGIn29zxCO8VxZ1S2jlLGSN1YVY18CZBW6TV@mcSVV47A3uOTOY06dFMa0WcGaXpEVlJvyiM2VoXJRbIoE@hW9nyNvbRAGhfi7RhgU6obUKQr3un9RjqlA/2j@GDMeHTNUyslD/gs1kLFC6FOpWzTLswWS4iUfexGZGjNRps5FJ45@WzcJdzRXSar7Y2tiwziUss0nNdo5nFy/Bey5hNT6AiwkfCOwDCIILysADicw/DXpwWPWP5KEZrwQ/lyeqeehmSQHXsTk4YRy9qsDdy9s/Qmzjyy8nrF6H@bV08ECIgbQYsuBUmmT25KFMzdybugbFDhjrmZ@Z@F0@uWd6Y0ufQ9cBasQuLy/7AOngAdPqGnl5jh7eL7sU0gH35UwXYnalUnuj5oqCdlKpvMlqmgABwpaCx942gAHo9MCWwv@qHhSSzZYUkFSqKMIjm80KuHYsCBVDYHRE5E2mVpM4D2ZzKp0QEfBTD/qspoWXn3b24SJtNsPTYgxEsMHEZZkgrsjjfF9BIB8QDc/E0YeFq37nzNy5k8VFjGwuE65WUI3ZJbTNZjaXRYoL//@Fr13x3ZztcT2bUbeVMTh1cOa2FR2cHXDmt5UOOE1wlrcVE5zTelbNbCvTusCEbW7Ik6GdkJo4MWZoN5iHiXXPsPoyvlFUE6kATdz2DWPXg4z1Xq3ndOmr4NWebOLX2fGtXp4hlxOrjo0m5mpobILeg2aJ5LkwqJ3Ru8eCURvIaLXEtXVL6MkdpzeXvcncwndzLMetxUEdjAcRC@gG6CG49rWTzeYqDdaSx854R9DyxVRDzcAAgj@1lNbSG8ZOsVjpyV3L0N2dfCVfSvfwtR9/i2snn6kM5C8eP3o4mYyfGvQu0E6uDBnQzhda5NkpVfL5VqMhiqkGFdPCbxpz8SRtbECfNvSeBE/cAPMkrdSCzD3TrdXi8Z2sqklqJZspXQoLwiHNsYZ1AbOmsGZppPu5LwEqtmODsKmk9bR5TlSo9Pv9y63z1MIj6OcS9wF9LiU93TkPvVUpkq7CpmnJXERCiN4Hcp/7e3sVUcuXxGqjuvAXC2K1dSncHRk9U8dXgJqZ8@u5CiCUOdQYFNRkwmXFdZxJpWP0HddYJMyqhSAhR@h6gpx4GRbXzGCJ59eLK0QSzc6vQ8nlxcswV4CWcHkJdOfEBrL7VlrrdFS2oZZzrX0QQcA@24EBV0wWe/5ciG09/Sxbr0NTn@eKWi6fy2vZQiFf1GC8KecK@RJ0tkwhk9c0gJIrl8rFS@BrRXkTo@@zsb3zgN8rZKE@oVe4icVGiyXffGpa56WsxPFIJKuXl7E3QuzDp59pMECuvRIw6H6mSfVaNl8GVxZdWhYQZoKmSVpWyqqSmsX/Wxwa/r97eg3@NbxDrqwmHKPdlU9h2ISh3maP0H7DxGHHDn7BZ8DuGd01KfaGOp1j3nMdz/t7pLmn2yc86r7JjZ2GUQ91/IyZNzInwzUpno1HaLLFcP/BIOyPOoAgikOe4B7cXMtxViUosmdP1tTycWheHIjB7YtD8qcHHz08jjyP93f3HgoFdu/w0/tXHnk/UZ492n9wHHqLPDbImg9B/OL@o0dXvf4jd/jsaX/quPgTHhw@yy1uYRC@Jivk4FpOFAYTEP@GXlIsQaOAiVi@GDhUAV@uuAOT4zu@M19YODPo/Jy/A2x64WF//jp4RTgOXgzWGUrajsG63DIPztbJap6vy6vFsiCMme2csWKG9RzL0vGb7P0NCBzq@JKjgQqtZSEnYtFnjmv1zsyesSE8xvcpyyp@/xqREB4CkNG0SxYXQJlBG6w9/Fo6bkt1rKnBpmO2NhAeGIRO1xwMYQw@c4IEQkfXGfze94L8RvSa3Bww4WVQ2LUY63pyISaI4p4oPtQneqxU9TKVyp076hNXLGfFMRDSGxj7M@BY9gx6kO7O0yVxIosPWHuAmxqWM47pMAFpgLpe1hqtnZxWL2Xy2b/@rR//3Z/8@qCmbjUze5ntncePYF6Tr4BgAx2WkZrqq7IyTWq0cilfKme1UrpULuXyaiGfT6taGuaDxTJMCTJqSS2U8mU1XcqVQQfJlSE2Xy76irASaL7KVgXA2l38GvM2zYvkIUyA@CYke53Qkyymh/4pEw3IIwo4BZ3Q6@JbZg2GT6ZmWLbIAKLOuiz24MFe5sEDUbyHHjzEsZcRxR568qVMpnhPFA2K2SuhPiU6PE8J7dqJE@7JZO4BjaccAJqEF8UhevYLuJgmiiZ69nYfPMBy@ujRMD8kO@Ex3GMFniIks9ED@jkBeBVCg2S7vJwcIbqPHiwSYx7wmD2IE8WPAnQw5ilPxgE8DGq6uyuKB9yzu4sxe1TtPEf0E/Ts0iWKLniA8UVxAI6BC11OFDvgRPYXxS64unMdwvDL12g13J7oojjn5EECieKMUuvdE1FsB@FYzGc@NnmkboU8Kq/1XfKU8U8UtQBpTJYNPVlRzIWeHNTt4cPP9OGkZwz4NXf5sws1ffgwq5uz6f6DzkcfdQaDjjvf3f/oKUbt7T0EXWQ@dTuDjp@x04bLgVx7DzX9ZDS/ekGtD9rtim6tjPqk3c7p9pWo9rxtIIaQ6xVg5l8DLGjU3oOovYftu/qqTWQC2MaeP4JnB697I3je0zs8Krgoip6zTkesIvsrSjMh4GwBt3@xO56AJLXTI73rOlX0z2osk0aFZd4oZFpVimAj0Poz1UuM7yfwruPKT/J83pjVMq3arFbU@CmkfkJszrS8KaY3RjtqOV/Z0HdULZeaVdBihdOPs7ik7rCEemfrNUt8mtzRYAYgNnd2JLGhtnY0tVQpFJ9vTUUxWcH7TrZYgYSZeIYxvCUbxdZOMR/JUiymdEWrFIugiAFRJjCed3BFpp1InBn6STKJ6OL6AFSB6srmVE@z2k/M0rMax4vNk9VZTa1ya7kscw1WD02zT7sTx@UQBwButpOp4P57QlTLJRHKV5REMhkKPZitC4tjn59//fjk@PgLUvjq/srFE/4t@arv/ejhnnxwGPjQqLr8APVQx5X3UGotxXCFNAg6hhmI/BCGUJjNBWH4ZqDrWPI@nZsDZTaICMwEyb6BU/n44RKco6FzxktGwwpVspJndw2GNufNHtNrdXDpPZYgrJiePKPBu12v19q1EdkegCoGuT5hZJB9AebA47iH5h4o@zm@LedHtGuZy2qnNovNAE67xiT1xcjpvdBS3WoPTc3fq93DzNU2PDtVo2a4ruOKMJcWq/0duza1Pb1vPDFcNGRycLgJqgS@QpfoMyO5yZr7mHoP5ymXUt1l9gKzT6ejhC7VO8nloIgXSZP4elDlc3qnE89nXFb7NZZ4nqy@Aq@7yRI9@V5yJ1ftJe6xdhJCMi/6L/pMY4VcleYYCYQE3Yhog3XWk7X6J6D9cMAnlQog4rfxCcDEkgCs2aMIPTk2L6vdmsUSEpuxJJEnVx3UGpj7Am/bkii2JKlx0RLqkvS5UIeeWp3H9Jo37dD3SVimo2qZQnUGYWoxVx1Cw@rPZ1W3Np66RtUCr7@Mx19d1atATqAagHl9kXj7S99Ibkv5Gg@rEqgLCxSOttyuzao2WjwElqhlaxCRauQyaZi7w62YhtFeK6TVQjqbzqWlIobCUJ/OpyEQ5jagXCSshMiYmM7MMrKaVg01nci8MHsvkumTBKgsRDKWTE@cfXs6YhACjYRcSV546iyZ0rYsmHP1HKZvS8SmICuqWDGg@ZCNzfQQQT01dItyJJMSy24lrM0Eptk8no73G61KZX82/jpEJaRXO4VUMZN6nUxWExvJmme8EupVoY5yhWo93gCe9Vc4mTcdNaCNwaUWtUqj0cEqFjPpbCYLtTPbF4NtsS620pmNggpNdMlIYDAuMaKLfqjrLMLGbdS5LQOaTi1rVUGmFbhsSZPKSn4rn@GrgDynMPYFG1KSJZpi8Jp2Ih4vavF4Ml7F/YcN0V9wBmlGkiwOYjV@R90RQQ0TK2JZwwQLoUhv4mYC7EARuxRw2YPlYEp7LlyeX27Xha8JR/h@5bb2HP@Kzx/vHuLf1yCoDN7S88fPDp8dPhCYQkc85XasulGVq@0qeCS5fleIVRgDGdr0bUgpG4y97@HR1Hb9OX828V0BgCuQFeMGa9GhLsPE@Rr7DO0T7LA41EF3Rw1Ny7YaWhFGPZCjQVJNU6u4OxPDtxHkOjSGdw74bafq@GrfJ2w@11NSMMm/w9ggtSkQeWJXVwB2a7uDp7vBubTdvdXrBJszBZemm6Cp4zm22Hk8Fr@EPyF2l1401PiLhiwWvmqIO6r@Zkg2V2DJcrBX8bX43Vg8HsdNgQrz3sSo3YJXtz55oQHLxGwnCIC5Eq5jwWCWz@PKeUx5Mfa@1ErZxweH9n33gcHfEdJKubZYj7GMKuELUdWKH5oX2xsnKnBMVsyepGPsboyO1YvlkiZqPKAaYydSXK2k09DIzY2LDQf3RFh4Uu@N/fHXGRvHs7k4Y81abFbL@UfA1XpdUrc1NMxWZBWQ/X21IGUu6pzH6xRR0CDm7S/9IDfbLoFfy6jg17R8SqvX1S2NJWPjt1/9PtrYOd//bPcRi@NK@t/9yY@04t/9yb@iw2bxS1pd17LFGKREp1ooxs7Px@fnl3DxuHysFeNI5YpJcPOdHjVWV1Qta9t2lVUUXd8qpnLaXbuq@GnVopqMeVLM37Mq5mPehR@lZUoQFWwqUZBYwBaI7T8185p6d3sHqrOTzWnVDWh/NXzRlIV/24ZXhtYtPX5xwRh4uvXeYGBq5FIUVnkjse030jZ7gxs6b6QN9qJWx4MBKr6eGmx4bOHrerjpF6@nlK04g6kRqzcuq5etFO2YwATyuWFs2c0rDNvcwPc1loO2bPgztjz6w0xBgAfewGdsvfTExFZSUXq90JDbtsHydeCKLQVw2wp2PfifJDWTb3/pNzSt8Hd/8msX7Yv2FxpMJsvlgqrFfvaz7ak99Yxe/WeQ8QbjKcGEkLaM0MoJOsKJJOM2D00/V@iQuzCHndqoNPP0wbQSJ5IMFA5zYBs9mlYKp6gkUUO2uf2@XoKSbaFthTQp3WQvK1kVhFA5JaXaHXTTBINtoaHORispnAsfYBSMxAwU86rwwQIUBIxg7HW6bc@aumN6uyVB@dRWmt2BLFDCB2gacYNsQvhiXAJ5pmxdz8pR9ohqpFCxkeF5aGgRRiDhA8jiWzO25myso/kSTGnaMG7ImITwpIheA8puQdkWz9Cm0ATVnidIM44dz2SD4i18AJoEUcEEBYOZ25CgClLoAyAA1CHhAzZbbJtlk@zcTKWqCyuOl3giH@1M6oHpBAGzIbQemuoIMlcxHQSBwo/fz0S@8FsYdLtIYACEw@Ab@DWYMmB28qHGRrZN3hkUwCI7YgmqGrtzZ4FVrWb2koxqhPBPzDEud1E72KtxBWDBdOvDXkVMM7SPWQ1CQ7YDiqcIXeA6iRvGrEayMhG9l4IA/@/MtMiRV5qKIqpYAb@9eK/oAskgM5Kdt2GXbdeYqhWTLES@C7h3CSl6gz2cQzZnH8raF0HkJWD4s1jwdRoQUcfRJUSfb6/azmCgZU/x0yBoQY0LA9/mBbeRhqLuYBLkDnNBVUyLUvdNF2Y3dLIgMM@YyKpJzLYwZ0l40Jl5Lcfw6Ho@iQ/KhakZPHU0M@iXs0HmkboONKg3dmyyS0h2k/C9AeAIkFG@STeO9tQ@w09J@W1DmaMYeWTODTkfMSY7i/QNbsqLW/sdFybBAW3SzBjIrDvqMa3MEsRoZHrODsElKRMh3AFVGWncsYwRoHRkGPSymVdRlAGoT9MO2d97bAJfDR@YMN7YnuJ/7lw5M09M5Rg/hSE5fXwnjVsziaHGhd2PnyLwbd1ZjnPCLPPE4CvDiSVbMB6DyQLou2mg7OIHhK3g8RQtm8bVCjXNU8GvCI8id5bSkbwbiXny@jOrbiTa2KIXNPiYLn7K/FS3I/Sl60Lw58fe3AusSZFNJPDLocg1fDsytThaiAgNJAm@XawamWSSccdhnBBjYmBPCp3C2DVOGc50BRxjQGh2A8ss2Iuhth/QAEB9D3oWmpmcuBW0JwSYuL1EF7qeL@Bt9iHLagIm5Ma@fMNcAAObvrYMHeIgK9bDm/SgYWRaZke5Ar1z1IM4tGThsx/mD7gb3WQCdMHebMMHh4MOlVVjvFsEnnzEg70D@ZmqvgGRBcBwBSYbCTEFYFNiUuSgw/xXs3NuF0iWVNh1SGmGEHxSAxRSFXQUOfTl@cU3nwSIuKd7/MMAvhHKs7MzmSyjTl1TNjz8DpLn2LqljAcmKNCOMjFGY/@LsyZ@adyHu3BJ/PNn8ng43pmh6lor35nzpyD0vZp/yCcR73txHBxP8TM/gxFZUUPzZR4x1AOTPhHWTfhnjjj/aa30ecB/FeQ/qRS/RCCMIZhZep7upgFYutM9SffPelU/4pQ6JACHVjSCQLRX7AaekRe4zHE/TOFMUI6GUR3rhPZtAZLIl3UXRfMaBinngdf3j80ZZLKNM7bruvo8QfFJTI0MnJiT2sPmMOxTDDhhmGHn3HiuOWvMW0vZZ2F2GNTCUwsumkgTzm8Gyi0pY/yMx88gfsbjZ4tCg2IbsxZXyTDoEquDXI@WNYOUCGYepLnkVocXMQQZtG@mchCYcr4Udgm/bo1yB/TmPmjHWsAYwBNjILiRUBrPm41my/aMs61WShkAs4tECGhxAN1oEU3PeqEbqW@dWmPHWwqy0aAqjEo@3hjUHfrcwHkF6xg2EDEGp5eJNjAHI/94BVcI/AoDBNTDIBJVg91JwkxWQ8vdFAmM0xAXNOaINXxkWqR9@VF@GKhLnPScsFFArQggDA@rBGhCDAt6Dv/qXSAdPncdSBOklehDXSO0xRZvxYGSV7oKlzVVaqQIVpIUoAlkR3W1drUqQTw0ReNKVKSal377R9HfeG/0@9AvVmNPDMsHjKoQ7Sp4ohFUCL@7EFVZvRZpV8BA2dItw4WRa5/rp/5oDcVsKcE0g5eDVfDOzEl3mIg0fjfJ24femxRtsRKywrxWgyrOa7xb8n4RkJQTPMzm@dnmASP4@bkAARiZldkMP9ssmm1Wq3HBwWZrsp1FkJwRkjOehaeerUGy5WeD2dNBMLxg87RAO8UjlyLAU/kwCmrQWGSefmrgJvhLtBOJWwl@mQuZQ1zg8xCq2Mhn3dbK0hsRpCNC6woAZMRrAHr8A7oV4arAU6XQF8ooTspARnGfzwZcVgCDkQiuclvKiZDJaA4MCr@YonEA@q6YagiiSovC@JfhPzEdBAY/9XpgZjmluhyYSV/5@wcJbCFlIx00on2omRwKZJzJPLN9I6RRnSOG35ofOqDVdc4cllihbEO4MvWzKh3L6SgjHQ@z4Gc1eag8nieD@QNuqLC7Y2eiT5xcrsInTSax3ary@ZzBHNgOfo0nYk8ddL2eY3h2fAKN2nUGtukZaYamLk8Mf9ph@B94EKJ6su90PEHwj1XxaSyC5nyFqm67jR/6brcTeFoxWQmPXtPhRWTPeFzA@S@4IvlBPPlAD8cJp/PS6E6St8PEjwP42Y7N7knicOxH4irpLgMZ1gX9H2KHoMEwz1nMHMnwOKrSnUmCPmoxdEbOALS@qScLmPsK@IMFbERIH48JlzTTcUpbiXwignpJopvWk37WT947K/tES@jJML@2DGCJGGnmXqUxUtZdUVx7bXE8W1De0fvjexTF9@hmfGkWfhVnPjWv8cj3KzqbWECAhAs0srejgVUHudW7hs4SKmEw6lU8wzuj2KPDYj3EdBeS7vrJ5T7wRzr0eeALEf9sHf1vbsAg@/67Np8O3Z4dzUHejPDcZYI@oOYFO6MJSH6QRNlzvbiQte@/Y1mQFr9d@QBVCFBjSXDZaDMZOuYYpt1euFwcAL6F5/F81jW@p0NbNR65Aif3NM1OtPVNdL/dMyx9bvQSfsp0BG5Q46cwYSN59W4VR0FHQs/hc70EjF3JMBaGcSQ6T1RZwzJ6@jSZXM9WPIkZcg@tlBOGB@vph/HXRDMu8dX4ajXMA@LxGC7Hnpq4/Dmej@fcLL/Fv57ly1E@/vCWRNsPtxME6MBHTzW9KDZ5k/h8mgir9A4jQphWXq4yWs0OIKJJpett@H4kur2m0LiRTLWglYXlD9KsbnHzphaPcEXAk3yX6d1Y8jame2eei7AaB7YQYXvvN4Rcg4yHObrdRBQiD7mxxRz7mkzAMFqns9eMKu0VAjXMSZJuYtJ0m/SLpIAz4wN44oLTZ/BEgANj0uYMFdQN17T8D1Iyihnp44jW4oeAkg5QIlTkJPfRiKQSAjckP78My@yuLbN7rczuUplhD1guMpJI6C4V6bcCNs9NTWAZ/cka6YxROHeGx01iGy7b0V1crTiPm/GKmWbx03gFBHLciFf2EyCU47145T45vHjliBwn8con4Fj0rfhFvBJ0C0zggpccdzHcF@Ho78Yre4nkpTDRTwwvKFeOV8I2hTQ73EsUAVJgvUFrxC022/GrOXENGNhIqUwz5BgvjdMnWodJ0y8D//wTU/TxGYzENc4tSsxSTF0aNCIjBi8Hho3g4wYrenLFH833Dx/QYagwCRaTgjleNA@BBzU8Fl8WRhwxjKUdDXgCgig3K6sxYpGR7B3R8UsHDqVGXi6fqCeTPtBLUHwDErcWhdB3xfz8QXstg@AN@G54YuZ1eF5DJyiOMMI92eQKtJCoL@I3VArbehkXv/WjLURr3cuJAFspSMJbicBGZDrocLQ5h4WNnfEyk1AsHrk3o3loUY53SuTeK9lIKvg9c000Bfs1Q8EQ7fzJm6oTyYeoLYkgjGxkWryXheMCyWKMWsi6iKbKOx@gEJE50MON7gl9s@3@/9vdt261kSzp/kZPkZZwozKlkoQNxghhCxC29sbg4WK3D2B1IZVAbd1aJS7ypdfM/DgvcOb/PMJ5lXmH@XWeYp/4IjKrsiSB7e59zp41vVabUlVmZGRkZGRkZlz0I5cTcePyWnHXMmTqSpMsuZJikip7iGV15Y@k9WjzWkWEqx/bvpqatzhryQKAVTNqReRr/wf0977o70ahNkSYaGCWYj17KZ1Wr@9dZScw78TNTg8gPrpq25mpHEUtxCSn3YGlmd/Ha1MqPkw@RMmXRiPoE9q@IVu0J/gG3Sb3FgILWsLwOvny4xK9/Lh0N6GmNZLOtWeUFg8taTjS8QjTuGv34yodnzXE@MLn237nhwd4mBxge/AAjzswnCC5zPLhVY@tXOK5TWJb3kCkFteUCHK@Lo2GOX5J4p6vbqNrW3qxXz/Y3t/bfU@L7tOnTx29Ro9j/DBrcdYareMCmS2ro/VgxrZlyUViJVx24zg@vOwPRw9Oe@kpWSLCmpQBn1ox7KfnuKNlmSXPJ@Yu1ZOyFkU1rI/xNPATUgmqjo8lu63pOiKCBKPsI18DMeot0dvl3ZrDKYTq9Z7fDep1Xr5MMl29imFozI2487fMg/xVOOSksZL/6iaV4qASantfvXtVOVJHr6pq53jrr@r9/rF6V9k7QjyBN8ebu7UtRf9X9w6rKpWwo0SuQGwoia7bQSNAAli1VCg8UQx5qz8Yi9zJbjny/tDvqlf9RoBrqvXQ7764lB9eLxhtSK0qbUfHOMNsc27IbnsEewtOZkjbWCg3TXYThCuAorLntKftYs/b7TfbrTaVTWHvO2gHofEsU502jSDJW@Nc7YqShLyFbDrE@UhhgXVD1X0qj7sbAuOL/RVIjBKS6LDpKU246L8fpuBR9eD1oUJoiq39ve3aUW1/71Dt7B/Qzzfva3sviZ61w6OD2uYxPnHB1/vbtZ3aVoVfCAIFTyFmxK9X4eheFDwUZ6o0PuLm2xvQ8Ee/kqfe0ODVjc8Ok6FauOpB@rT9TvtT0Fwopa5CqC9w0uSrApWdrxy8fEtrvgp@ww2nuQpm@4P0cci5NOcLap1bo8myQfOtpKcrLXu5osP3Ed2xQjqdoMSxJLL87CoDnI14mu1Apbdgo4Kzbwk5wXPZgKaGHhBsgDIGK2XFabAWFtx1BrlBrTU6fcQHldbEiFD/QNUXxtSklGKKaVsZAIWzQ62H86BiKXpBfE8vlnSzo6EUUI@jF1JAPZEXUEVrsB1Ry7rE1Wj/CuJZrciLX7uDHb4WVk@jF5s@72JXNU4ybjykvorSCCIAR4eTnckpDydk5UzbXCXk8kgE1unIxAgkBSXJRLlKZNs2KpkmYdPCVYM2e5PMzvhK3AA7Ib81ClW27HjqCMZBQa8taeYuOn5PTKBi0x3mPbWKWEdl7Y/djtKzsfvIoM8MiNSQSTyiettaKwy@tx7V3Jxq0dc2kpwi1ZigfQuBzSkE/ggYApRL7HQavFKxDyvA9FualbNhnzgS57a/2@WJnZtXjSBRQVttZX9tf/rkaCK7iX2SsVNk7GiIPgVDUiv5KrPVH9IcZ7HKCa0gBRuX/cGoLWOYTfaAb5x4maPSWNiotV/KG4nWQIfJFnv9ntXoOXHxHa2eE1N@T6vM8XJ3HomvONMxcT4twmJ3B3T88/51YN2dubhEuglw/EKKMN@V4/BzPGJMRP9MxbLjd4UEqavlje3N09zvv7jIkipiQZIUG6ND/E@MibZoevA9HxssDqF36ZlmstuFV@eorW3wtLTELDfAaB942aZ93Yt6Kfom5sbT7@FgM/meX375UpZaOUgmndk6vMzG0s1VJ6ZJl@ucKW0CYslOQpZkfda8cRlmJK9fwKkGo4DgPT3IEezbJ3LHaRFiend@1SLJolP46uGO4Dtqgy0q4vzncJaxxyP/IbtZXtxw8rFBibLImTUi2jWQi45jmaXwejUFbvt@cCS/vx/c6r3YyfLwQ9C274X2Q7jlFu@GJcuSBev7wf5@D1hZ3P4QWOq7ezdgWSSnoUWcHjGnO5@JrGnvb/GXqbHjuUdgsPbiBCUCarV21eMrahNtOysVHBtMrBAdHm1XDw5UWvYnVJfkHrYMTS0GAfuBehNb27Z7LOy8SGmKNsuR8mTeJCzaIveleybzTOLdISq0DuJqekTCIo7p3WrfitTTKwurEGx9zwLRUC6J3Wcjg8ITDfgr7QEJ2XjQrA6mZnYzI4tPO7SNwDXdXNGNbRt@trCWtRuJcYdjG5BtE@RfwLNk9vi9E/14zbQjChYiHqHDTdKkab2hfcIhNTyggp6XHMF7hsUMKYzsRcHOGNrB8KuQ1LD/PEMxI4kSLrqwJda1cqxRE/143qg5bJCIZcCHpaf@KBbN9MGIeH6zbg@oEy962eQSREomUqW@sLmCqp991UsYUyNaJ8uRQm7PtXnG5sRgeYbTWQ27dHehh7CFXpkUD5NNkbS9t6nc36cpWSUSLRmaz@yM@UiQV5aXH38L9mQvTPXcn4Uta8ik/Bx1B7S/j0GG45CP94lza3uu@R4zwD2kE9N6M2EmKpKqM2NNSfSdFyMbP8JFzoUIGYSoR/bZyVYddTuB22zosiLZ0LnIVB@sKRx1VGbNFPW/3t8cBPI323vw4@3JZEMhmA5@hVX@6/4wDGKvPCu@i/UKzvHJd8Fw2ONi4s/UBZQsuzHd62zH3nZi8Cq9wke@b7N70tLeSWJ265qzBm6Ejxc9JJzG6V5p8ngvVyzZXd2p7VbVIw5Z2UqcRaaHaceSPQ/avfsQYBnM5xJYPtiH72G4Rv8TDq4BSWRib74s08b5Jm5MEdKaTziHkTYL1bK1ODn6rbDh9xARxE0/DFXa/Ykq8ilsdX/HmXWyXigl6hNy4aCXpVpuOueluSq9w4EuICVByGjivbVgwVPDWErCveaiD/soXGwFt3J6xpaTfr64Wlh5luLe9dyR2z15duY@apTTihZfv9cNr4Y3zY8X/cvrluqowa/nt43xp9@UWn6iHlNbSz9J3ODiSjnPoVqf0r@r6lmBOVcj@JxjICMBsieZYZVaUPE@vPRAOfzAm@Y1eEhMcKl61DVcCBe7Ubl7snJW7pULpe5J76wEJ7/RYnm0WFzM4sVPtIqSjJGb@ZPRGdZU@9Q16F0rROfkDKTaNUSxawi9ee0P2/3dyt7LxGkcFAAcgWlbbz5Ql2TTc7Bmg@@J1wtusvqYzFXg2BQUpNQcewUV4fzO58k4jmm2CTMaFZe02fCW/x07qbmCdzUY9fmLicUI1lJf2l9Sc8aNqcAnClTkpG0iNsK/gODEZbK4GJK3Y7GizhVFXSvCd9KxQJygJovD9Gk6DZ9CIKp9uU7OUqEX@I1LIIHs6l@4mlpf51zrxGqhx6d4MOXwh@wwUTjDIy5A6M@AbxvQBGvuIbt9pKj7@F3Eg7zhM6oR@8mwgXyKNUV8gfm3@sz@TVx/nQgghJ8TncvTR5xa8yJFUnwH@XABgc6SG39cM8CtUgZlDp0FbGmvHANnS3GmEZrVZKL3czcgp9CK/tM9yBX511Q3ovKOFGeS8D21/hWCljyk/GkDfzpxtaxVLWeqmcIWKea@SQ2cdNH26HVA02qstoJOh5AWWszF5MAj@/fq9hej9sMTtHkWIS/fc1Pfc4nvnnwXpOJSHi3wcaE1u1A68zku91Wl42LuVFtlxcqLRyPd8EglicuW7isbeqN@vR0X3oiGUrgy@rCe@JCzvnyYMfry5UGiTsTg0fcT@a75e0mPfIRlouyLZPv4m9IDFLDxrLY1meBSr9fuPE/pxNz6C9gsTdRUSqpz6kVlJlVZ@2BqcUIaHM75edpulGMoi0UjcXjOpDfWX6Q9rWQ8z06iIV6MUxNrxhyxqMRtLjLhbtlhkdrhzw8sEAwTjKbMzN0wlce68tgCi1IPTLPiBTk1walrk1O8DL/IL/jHTPYkcqZcZvbHOcH8Vjov3s1JArHQfZCeTaakNIG7iLzUnbpnFYnbHk9CnC0k9qxT4KjNQHywWzgGfxDJCVtQGEkxRffoi6Z0XKBo2PeuIcTHr6m/5R@lXvqkYw86wa2qYJvhsxdWKuHgPgrCUYjAUBy0JrwaDDq4dWSF74ZdqHVYkaVlXLfEEK2V3UvVYNkj5V08aYd0quSpfUC@gYFI/CG8uriAMxk8YPs3EK04cWmPvFSlN5YDDZozj5fEzTxQCL7BArjTvrCRkJGT2QNKhwO/EXgp0tFC0n5S0tVWWycs5fN0@I0g9BgtaWup1D9dtRsft17iPvdpsfC4aJHsWl8HF7zHT2IHKyKS@bCE6IHLxSeplHU33JC74RwAumoXC/1b4s3gOuj1glSFVgwuGJLSGgbD66DppVIHQXQJDLhgZdxMwg@7fzVsyOEOKV0@MSO8hENXrsOIw/AX67NcFzf4rsxN4dIqvm2mob5uN0FA43HS6uN2mC8sECZA6IFK3WBERHnkqCRKfPescWHdpYuDKKIG4pxYdxMRGXr9UbtBI8MnWakOgZJrkLixXnMCE2qv0fHhHOzNQgDuMTEFDALmKuk@HFL60vyHcFC6Y@aO3Tcjkyfp1@e5QtM9GLZJ@sYE5lHhahbuNMBHr2qH6nB/5@hd5aCq6PnNwf7b2nZ1W22@5ztuXJRzFF71an@XpEt0my635vv0Il05pJpp/pCq7L1X1Z/fHFQPD9X@gaq9frNbI2gE/qCyd1SrHrqqtre1e7zNt@8EQe3tH6nd2uvaERU72ne5VVMtFddT@zvqdfVg6xX9rGzWdmtH77nFndrRHhrDrX5FvakcHNW2jncrB@rN8cGb/cOqQsdS27XDrd1K7XV126P2qU1VfVvdO1KHryq7uxMd3X@3Vz1QbCRg9XKzSlhWNmkLi5a4n9u1g@rWEToUP20R8QjBXVcdvqlu1fBQ/blK3akcvHc10MPqPx1TIfqotiuvKy@pc6nsN6hC47J1fFBFtCRQ4vB48/CodnR8VFUv9/e3mdaH1YO3ta3qYUmldvcPmWDHh1VXIZ0iN00wiFr0nZ43jw9rTLfa3hGtGcdvYO/g0CC/I8IQlhWqus0EhhkEektE2j94D6igAw@Aq969qtL7A9CUqVUBFWBRsXVkF6MGiYhHdjfVXvXlbu1ldW@ris/7APOudlh1aMBqhyhQg0HGe2IdavSYe41xIrzkkZg1ZTjX5eFUtR1V2X5bA@a6NHHAYU1zC5Nt65WmuYc4vdYhSruPMwO/ax@stKZfXQeITDl9IjP7jCaKmLS1v12lFVmHtkrHH45p1VmdCKVkf6OVJvpIPxMha5rB@dVFvd1r9eFjGlWTg49ueOEiSZCDDCunqXtyZenzFa6QydTrbyt12uge1uuO@z01E2h8q4Y@Br@vlKP7iAwM2Hnj4GdtTei@niDUxk/6opMN9XABgZJC/Z/E9M3vBo7K55uBrgbnfQA2R0ehXJtc4iqFRCM7OyI1TNwkn0zw77ZmB66YNeC9Rh3npLCM5EL9kP7pfYl/yOJgvSDpLMdd@Tw2sYxG@1NgmpFGOCQC/6MjErRb3KQXBsHHi2zBbg57fu@i329mHcfU4bIj2gdeZJ1vVD8PLiaq5ybrM7J87ayTF4Rm380qTHT/rEmm9Lh4Q@5ZFv/UR/zHMdhIzAecmnJTfFitDy2zP0l1WCS5Soe2gHsFDzJ0vteVn2vvsJsrLD0pTbx/Fb2XuQV7QcSwpQXvhOud8Z9XZ1KAJhjH4iCStHWEjHzeqmPsTaLCN1TwEoVu2k1Y/tBafRnwuk4kIUX2yu/YbWI1HrZvbexJDr88qLzePN7ZIdEJbJ@sLj9dKaWisFs/u/L3PdrhMLMcdWxA6zjpafzJmiVbpPjwTLGifMfszwycz6MgorebQeOXiPMQ2W0kLZkgyNDdEHmSejDRSwegQ1pxAI4HKcOvM2emZoBsoqsOetP1b1nF90lXYh7QxiydMY/aLf4B7Gj6mykedUgzkGYxDrxLnEu7C5Z76R1jKsqbGw7cgyJe2vCxhHGLaMBHXWw/C@9a/qV52xrFUEwZMV952LkmIfFgEgtl7Cp6MrPfcJwRfQDM0cPozc@a3@jxvQ5wx@Hu/HBUGR0SGXeimjinjg@jdadPNOQzZNNAUDXT0rrCKb@jkeK5p4@To8Ag1mxgVJAaBja@ScClKI7IZJNsAftiwVGfhVMRvANwSppj9W/i3Fnd0VBKJn6I/m2iUiiBFQU5EardRG2kTJH3URwLQ84Emf4UPRj@P5AmM@Cv046ToMfUsoIAfhclGarQiravTJT2jblosG43Ymrar97HYL7aA3MZdUzf3tyKfw2RQI/O2Lx4z2EPW9kZBACT42DDnr@RSdqlT1unF2lHV8c9Sa/RHWSVXivMUjEFN7dy5rLa5Zq7FfxwlCNnTVaDu1RVvZCN2znPetoyTWzl1cMwLeAcE/8j/4gPQKIJz1x6KVark5xV0LPMyAEdaslacJpRxCRSS7/eeWv3SFkhMhOyX998GUIR6A3gM91PTivSV2Kem4y4yCuxOuIoeAgmjm0yFh8dsu6cDTE7AeA8bPJhCDKPjG6wQHQEOofqi6Gp7EM2FEEjsdVhHGcQ4tbxiLS8rN5E2PPJJDg0wv64J3HsAznVMiU8CfChMbTd5T312h8Typ3v67awWP7RYd@F7SIak2MJXR9ZVhr9/pBURx/9Jhzd9tjx1Dt96BD0wquhjl9I61l7qE8kjNJPzUBtkt07LzMSQJ5RC9sjeCs0PeYP7lI3gIWohCe5za2oLDGv4dENc@jYvl0squx6/GWdaMJhSZmI62pFffkipYSgOmRowBRsh9Hmgm02uR3cO0TT76Y//Ii1HypQrxk0o8ikFkg@C5RBqvU4xmNjJF0f9EM@0aChwAlIRImiHKRFhqq0Rj/V7KTtmtJxdEzELuWe/Hg7EZMaaylqKGZc3Tox30qOBhNUWtKhQaNgocWlZUZl1obr652bMY4Wmry2VunTXiRS1kSJKD80qiOeRG5GT@/xpA/5yw9DzB56gzturYICYeisuFedlnOMH2wK3rWDYdM@EyVNpukPcPzGW59@j3nRHB3qsH8NfxQGY9oBNPLt2zzDqGf/0r/s1bf6Hf@i3W/7tE9DDPhbkXh4HPMjBuxi2L8JOYEQf2hahZrj@Fniy0gYNvyO7iVLVmiucBQMsraZwmg4rlxKmAg@OYcRYJy8lPl7MBkjLarzZDmulEr6n7I9XtEp3Vn3cXFWZbnRBwAt4DYmLCjEh3TEjkmW82lpqsD5fQUsHM9VTvnOHRZ7CYyfEYn4GiaBsUFmyizB7gR2ZndifNK8dZscg3CIQEvBdoB0OGGWX7s@8kGTFHkOS4E1VVwtWFXlFuUWcQjxML6b3EtP/8HYEwJ/Av3i41ncMosRWMS1TLSlUPYrOsoo4cLmgW2W0SyJSYq1L9o9y/2QM1DcTkJNfh7fRQ22/CGlSIfZm@JKzMgsbXyQ5y5bJ5FTHztYVBbUgsNxO6CCVEbZwt0MG3zLfpYnPy5x5eQMgmlLQ85aSN9FqgZRCRl3J8xrbZQlpvK3Z8zS0veO2gQBy7NMzqzMz9m00VzYA6Ut6yuutfpDEsbpCeppU4@FcNQfLHwn9e6UHTMjs82idcNxvmkILMxWpsXyUZNJWx7jcVxKTeIzwTRJirGlGfEQtq/8HLH5JBFvy3XMt3J9/A063EWz2G4qWlSi8W7K3MeieA2LXrPQRFOKcUeQ0lL0/qROHa/fLUE0TNle1Vli1CEy6mN5tEBNkCmi0vdTiLlP4z5BjyZRDu02iXb2@NxJ1EkjORPy1HxKBLkEPRG4HU6bJJcGLRhfIEycaLiRkIoUzlt3zFd5xdw5ggzjgwCEVhzk4nMoOcGNB2uCjzg7QCtbh7VQEZKInjZsC4co6H9EMI7Krw93tMVDfZwrnpUE0m0EiXYVXOo@SMbfnH6e1G8ZyhQpaIrPIEXUoynZdPn9vfqzfaFyBEFq82dt6Vtw0RlHLRI29I/9qX4LHThuStdMzKjkRKizaKC5QLuUi04g21Vof@2hcDysG/Q0og2EvM7iz6KugXDeK4WI2qhy2xyjiKPJLbPNUbkNqRIzlPwG@fVUFFWXN64EIBCMqX65SBAQ1pSxx6UAh96xOS@BqB4jqlguYlrSS46KGtt5zvgOouoCT5atEoVZJZ7ZMHIzgZBiMbtMjAjpLLOLxFBooZuJi1Xi6ez@xCVIITa8LxSnodCjkqRhNHJCQE41XXBiiXJSVG5BczB/fLLsJD5G/M1fnxWsr4XJr0SfCMOTXHHy62oh8TXR7NJSsmqiJtHDsVtNfCRSODbCkVT4c/@xa4od8jyyCbU2GQktQ9tnIxU47TJp3@b9Gqp1dso2OoaBZ3uGm@1XXVKsJIKy3x@AXS3wlQFit//p3hrLVIOJzhXAcemMs0tWNoSssaax1KNb2OmaSHtRgAKzp@231NujnZ1E2NfzsTE06gbD5UKhACY@t4PfG9tqHCW1@/lk6XzrqtPJD27@Mnx7nmfZHwScEmDN7KADGhKaFKHXH15IZgjgQEVROqcdWbHXv2q17BQMuKHE4NGwSUkdDUHxAtSOjF7eHvEBEIPUC@wv6CD694uKZt@NL4qmhmKuoag2TIKv0@b2jMiDFy3YZ0c3VQwMgtlYM9G65ZQ3PmMFQWYTHiwOX@x8js2T06@CTqfvqndIQYxIAXNfJyvs7NgVClIEN4zs3XsVcjxaVwXX7Y7lV4wiNq8DnFmYTJ4JExcesfEPgovq7SCbPvmQpmWFuryIbi4iPrWr0hdpRweL/w6wwoeE9neV7vqDbIPpNFmYlno9g@Mnwuhx0Z2590kUcfhMTNPs26VB1NnoehysgbrusC5gYtnz8HJP7igeETd9eltsgYYFgaFxQsyV76sBV7N/nFi8HrVa3ycVOQ2ADOwPSUTJhPLnBCLfAfAM1NOP6Iko2n/N0bTemQgoIgoOknVMyx1UqKNCKvWwUf7tJlupVNT8YHFRVSqb9JDLqcpmRW3jxeam2qbfm/j9U3lpebkkMnfb@UwvN83Lr2qTYPAJ52LjcrhNP@lbGX5jsNbGEM/ny/Nuab5eXt8ohfmTyibc@unpP//lf/7nv/6vfEX/@Hf82OQfJx@iQp7n5ecbn@d/@lrC75Pts4X585P5wdnCRQlc9jeOGt6vjXJ@bD7qDc9TGVkFrLdsR2r22Rx9RldVJgVg1x9@JOmypjKNMJ/Rb0PJHMUyNtMIrPcB/CjPaQtvkg5MbuUJiQwBHeM4nkanEcAAj9YboiThAjtQqS93K@bgHuFgogLRrUpGR@JhnfU6gE9LHEkBvri0YuXavTDo4QT8mnVe6V4q5dPf9qiu@Tf/4XV4sdm/VY9Os@pRQT1y1aN0mv8UV57RW2c@34Z3rhSj7UA67dKX@GoBZoYqbLOix/sHzrUzQe5Uap5T9gCSCVPBhcULzo12f@wsIwnXwovUHPJwKjki4UsmVMl8nu99pWH5TCW@phOuNqwo1PUuhhuzblSi8YUK5IdiCBC33BWCrPWpSdz0sUcynvLmjR7rFGcTYsAg68HLHZ73eEFr0XxP2zwn9lJIc8Tm8/IWa2NJnKEZbXyR9mME@EJFtpMF9iRcyCykxMrb6iV3U7yw7f5p5hNbh3EwMrbpUul3ZTGBWHPbhJvvab8Wbcgt1ysq3Y6uV6ym0pO23yplVeledUbtgXZX4NYxoT5HrX2VmYQRZUACR2L2r03PMD4oMJGiJoZFkmWNVbOPrstM6GnXdBpgx5ObI4sI@Q9ZmttfJua2k2cvEcMOwgOMVGTK1/LbnVBHXRkysS/84TmyA/otTqg2knszPs9DPtUJjPutCGmPIbPJeTyfqSuZwdC/6Pquyuz1j4b@uEbLFmk@o4bnUA8RgglIYPLppmd1zyAsPdJDwhSJusKWQ0he0Bnr9GgytunI5wRDaqaCDruCSZBgJ6Zk8CUxVhN0jLn6BwbBRnlKeEe3kVrEsuSFpZGGlLbdZniaTU2dlGnBnjvRxEmnBNVoZhpe0JWusNB2@eKXJHkHMQJ022ntBahdEVaeoX2sThdBz08sToNOyjj650tK1kXMZ05FKdZIKZMntRhnvANWpEd@SEaBkLXJhDNKzWWzc6ehTueWsdcRDvId2eLnfdWOEtBxAjP2DFHHvbYIy4kVKs6B4akaW/4ThFbHvyD8xjf@GKx4msk@f5B3Tj6c9s4eZU97X04/OYyJFslmlc2pjL7MNhJLzxVaGfNu4qexSgtNqMHTXrLAaU@JD4tFAkIknz35kD/7kieETjNISX@aEYIkhgyY5O9vLw/w@Sk0M0ks8pnUnPPIMYOffV50FK2t/BdjKC8c@UtYmE0lH9PTPmfYIlDsp/vblbichPnVpcKTpeIT2gldBLe5YXCF9TYXXp0Ht6RKhNjO0tJz@inBDQlCfL0N/RK9vKV@SloT8T0JtZOSFqF6mnM7qYitqI4nPEHlicocLhUuLk5UxsflIzb8riKWM2U5FpSYDlrcl8X6Gfa7aMcPIdcmvUOEI2FlIDYifISaA2STfOUuDnXMdFlgPydPbSF2KwOh4c1nrNWi1@/ltLLmeAslKNHwmumsFlYLk3N0aoomZui8VqYWHqjixvOn//Fv@79lRpmNpfy7If0dZX7LrKxm5JEe6Ndj8@s6s5FZR7GVr5lxnvbA9Pj0P/431d/4C8HBl/E6/bOxbGCtjDMbuTJX@ZLZWKGH4tIStft//vmfqQ/zsmNDLtb5uqsYsZKhyJbfY96l76qGXsq2dCEWK@yYBRhiYUh7c/oBw6jbpdUCH9NltFXFdaAjXxl7FL3Es2HWiE2F5CTD2FOQZiQVymggJyCNCUVLWbYbxmwDzBujqX556K2EtAP4RZtzRE1GphsPQ5gMzcu2iAYwKy3Sfl4eNgrP05F5x1ra2JSUjAqJrZ2WtauPS8QOb/rBqN1IWkmY6dpt@DfBuQc@9ILmFe2pemGn/@swf00s2S0ureZbONzPsx13fsCQcoOx94kUQZ0MiDaGbHTqqiGNQL@LEF4uZwsihX4nupMy@SRJyx4EDTnDSuYkpiLi4@fK9TC648WqdJb/JQUemTN1IkgrV9ppj2ruH6yp9GJUUMrxntcBNm/YOFaHwMiJNeyAZZOX4j7gdND0x6sML9gJiWsh6roU8fxms@7rb9nUXNqkSnNTc5dBZ1BOtyS8O2Kn4sZE01/UzDuh5No4QcjlWNABVjcY@bRFL6f5DfbjcQsIk6LvWqNQcTFZW7qs3tU3y5x15Z6mb6TpGxpRaAlxOxHPWNHYlF1MZEsZR5XDoI4rtZkNU2uhSdo89PgPMAhlWGotuCXo7rAHJFEt7o62KrOHzeW9MPHITSA@e3K0KJmrU5nY@dE1JcSDGroT2vWkMRIQiIK7Bgtl@n0oHhBlk2a03UtJPL@Jzya@hwbDfdhHKFE7bJ0EH5VlqXeN3DftEftSKiKBjitr22CnZPWIQEchtqIUtGkcvKQdsFRrjTdbXNAMxxqngTYhodJpOac6aagovWxLZ6@VRBH0Il0oLj1@srzydPUZspzN6d7OBoNKHnYBg0ufYLBGnaVNNt6Xy@mFtLxCCurpJgF9FlhcwMGs68ZxTNjnG@dBuVjQwApphnXDaTSkuj6uZJAxxGHgYUWgPUp2mM5mn6@doGNnp03nC/1P/G3iAzLDmXC0vpDeGoc3cWSqVFcCDpRZMHNQnOxjRFBx9Be7bNBvHSDaRABbV2F7amgXESBGl8P@1cWlzR2eDm11RBOGCM5xqbGDehmM4gBjFlbQRfWBQ83yvigbeCfTPYBRLpYE6HwCnKaZjlvpa0tTzI4FWoQQWRMeq7hCtExHbXZm7uz1VXVvexKxjJ2GjuF6tmUrKXccyQwBZJCr1@ruEVFXR7tgV1Itk9xEVGUWcAWUK7I7vA9f6QYSUVtUMbKa9YZR9j6yFJkX49CmcVUaR@A1A2ax8G1SGr9W0wsQxAhCfZoUCTE3us@xSRbjZA8y5il4Ob1m2Yi@bochB5jTjaUdbVHKhTirwFzqDoA4tymkpSOFNYwoP1Y58bKMNpI5ilc0jga0GXK0Uw1mluQ0E2x1G0oAbGQdN7RA/2t7W67artI/O@@2XSjKm5W/ot9Riue78S1qfItrqrZjhsCOFss2t7CZ@g0uSsQsBR0wNkYQwrclWRGDOGpAtbajaS@T@iQxt89irgC7@loJN6ejepIg0AufgczpzXsUioPddfjdmhxeTUuaKKSKnhZyxHX/xLZoMhe3GkESUn4HiKVJEFGglpjb52KGFwt01rx9vXcxjF3bmc3TCZaVDRWp7Tt5InuSZ@@kzH1ssaTZYmkN43gfXzDf3ssb50Grr33RIub4Bm88@GO8kft@5sj9t2CO6j@GOx5r7ni8Btkj3BGFDWePTk7D3p/BMedjXoPrzfZFG@dDLesnOlFwLQAs8IAhfEjpY7GAvt0hTlR29ofFyfUIRkJLy3AM@EOdf6I7/2QNMpcft4P/qp3P/Z07v6w7v7yGtWbGyGvVzgq3/vfpcawSZpMvZg4v1F0p5vzRnq7onq6sYTWdMcz/33ua@3/U06e6p0/XEDFBLhwkfP393CyaSOVwq1aLzS28lA7alUUe@9lc6WDv1SynafPQ6lyFl2Vo6@oP47@q8V@FNOInpKHDXURkGxrt5WV7Ks7yolnyKYeCk5X0RPprIqNb/dULVrwf0QuUCGk@2BrqjQop5K58jG@bvFh/jKVvtPh8L84i23WyTFycWxto2REWnXiKi@ark2QurUTryjbHQFZbRwe7i/9DyND1P2ovNEIeQ3sTdDpmJbG3YEdR1CndGas7gH2o9xwJVtHkZGRH2ts7Ype5u6UaB7aYWBdnbxLkqg33f7SX6kLfsLJy48iIaOPp@mZXBdNcs72QN9R3KTS7y7rHf4hLn2kufbamDvTG4C5S@frAT/NivE9bWl6@bw2QWh7@YAIWXCp/z6z6vw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/w750f)

Command line: `ccbi --befunge93 polyglot`. <s>[CCBI 2.1 32-bit Linux binary](https://deewiant.iki.fi/files/projects/ccbi/ccbi-2.1-linux-x86-32.txz) should be used. Windows binary doesn't work with polyglot and 64-bit Linux binary doesn't work at all.</s> Update: now using [64-bit version](https://deewiant.iki.fi/files/projects/ccbi/ccbi-2.1-linux-x86-64.txz). It works after `sudo ln /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib`.

FBBI supports `;` instruction in Befunge-93 mode, unlike CCBI (see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146544/hello-world-in-multiple-languages/147056#147056)).

Simplified code:

```
                    v
@,,,"361";@,,,"362";<
```

Answer (score 2):

## 364. Befunge-98 ([CCBI](https://github.com/Deewiant/CCBI)), 16084 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8;s0::&&1Pr"93"pllasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrlop#std[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 001-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;@,,,"364_";# _'1:,,@9
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD440TD@0ekQHWRFAmAAL9JkSqVStWl7qpWTUnV3W6SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uNl5suXL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuyJY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3R46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbEsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6Tza/fSjK/HVDPtIh0KNLWN2JXtVZZ@bhtu7mkJjnx0/eHDVN8s@kRybPbheJDXHdqcT52ByFX6e7Q4MW2eaXJa1q4EFQObEsEqZUuZqUBHa05iY3aV8IOCB6ULr6n4rsq5uQ2thW24xYzSezJnE21@3rLBtPaZ7bOpNdYvi2dNRx3CDiN5EdyemPWBn5mTIJkPTC9NRbG@sdw2pZ1jmyJwYPWaZkMjp@1AAtN1jJ8b8zHGhyX2Yjm3NIaHRNfsmJgnKAQDxSkyGBocz0ufQyPYEiIPpzINiWEYALSnEIP59ozMdMGc6GU8nDMrWMz29YwHQzpz1jL4@tSZp1oEwQDL5nw0N2ydmACcDiGOHl@rllIpmLGhe7/VYBugYynFiMBOwRsWqsGwW/JnjAtYgVlAiHxjRNa@jMYM2gybqOxWWz2QgfD/0wdLqluf4hVkuGgba0FepzRDuE9cZuPoIsNEzCKefHTxhXtdx4Q1@GJf3p5vAdPUJ295m8f1P78dZPWwW2e0IYRPV2Dk0QSwIZKe6NQUKibaEA@3jhqkFbLL4RrzC4oAWLcNyOZaDbltiWh6QpGbK4ID@r2VV@BWYVmI5FXpQPp7GfPquPjAtg0MZIJQiEr6WZxrcMzmWVUs85sCx@jxalzIrsmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYPcEHSOqeU8/ArwA2hlKIoKv2yOA1rQPdAp0toe6@sj05r70Al8l@VVVgSIUF4VIGslgADPbBZ/WfhRsZavKOzJELA91E8BvGSZJ8iNjJAhYRMq8FC2thTiiMhyefbeELMH1AHS8iVWhOwLgIkcFAEwq5Ug@3yGV8QbGpblJxt6mIxKW8zAD0peBDyUAPsZwGUGkVmEH7wDv9OAsWnAxTRgTBowE00DdxazgHgFCCtAUxZ8fA117wQy4vloPUI@cHQAoyK2kYmpiCSAAK3FstBmBZYDQsgiIeSzDMoPZSkWGPCxkspKOVYqMsBnOcOgbVQoF1KJCvxThfKoCAzaXwUCUKFMKmBbBaBqNs@ECLLVLIZD2iykBdSoOUiTAzc0nFrAH6QDylAhSxXy1LTyggihbFoe6pvPEnVqBWjdIoQB3jQoqwbkpEFptRKEY9oS4LCExFuMpzkidMQDtAqSO9AhICMP5SG4EBfcWjHL8adb46HeQW7NU3b6mLSA3aCAaISkGawePHOITShKBsBgL4Dia0ABWUBHFpo2mwuzt1QA0kDwRs8kBm2ZwLvUEEPFNBHkS308WaBNLVCJxvPJMPTTuJ8DjNME5mcM9O48DITelw4DF76FLPpqxGsXgDI59PWAszpTz1oACR05jbIyTk1r4Vciv56h9/qmN3yzKGuOMukY@sQ2Txa55PPpCFL1SEABA5a8itlo3IkpwXA1GKJrURetiHHGTthAS0VWVSpex@hP7YEhlUuR8lHIZOpOYGBZ5Fnm3q45GMCYvICjpqmaNFAuvPNUQiubnQihJ2IX83RNGL7vsO4QBIowsMzhl8sLGFkNYcz1Do7qEkhhMAqUcdzqmzPWudOlUWNRwCzhqTs0x0HkytrIkcalTGalQoQ2CHOvS5mQNePVkl86pp2Is3hSuBRgrOGSZXSkhgHtcxylcNxF0oVx1SGpYcE@E3YwMiYBacuDPIy6FrBRaJSujiMwjkcGjacBHHMiM8gExEDDOUWxlQbFpWw8Gjg7LkqpIOX0DNdlGBdEWy9NQ6w37XjGqynKUYty9WHMNmBo7@umFRaAxhF9QgIAPOMe5DdfLnbfdUY02IxwCLUcZ7xGXIEB@wwBPXTOjEXRF@O5Ph5bIDWBv8GFNijMmU7yNgnn0Vx5gSARpoMGB4CUFUgbpmt0Cfd@1SF1FuSS5SJWmFa/k0Uo9yLiVBY6C4gaHqaxp5ZVATnH6LJsXekZpwr6cJFrWdTCMgRCGIhSPoiODrIylpxKEUK6o8kk3h0HLes5o@Wq8fH1IKz60ETByDrT59B6fRhajZk@AomeodgMPZeNgGJ4C2JLgM6C1TpgPceOT0IoZy4IsVDpsCYkKCNOJubIAO3HgSTY4jkqNI7uVLLOHEiZsJWTSd3hJbmCKFm4iijukYt48M4C4l5v2kWsYd6mTRQEYpKHMr4LrJL7CROXNZs6/FyQ58a@hiejAyMeYdEiCoLHe7sveXcJIsqohu2BWuHJzET9Cyh/4PSB2M5MqDswLEi6gN0lJCAKQq@Z3JUFQjkS0OjEYibrjscM/GFQAvJ8kCmBCOq8NNlrCLSGoEJ0p647Z7MxtIQ5gliTrtPvA/W@NsZDAMFGPdadd6F7QiMj9Qg9hxhMd7xczcXbpgFxbFRK9p78IhsYgHYQWPuonSLJLyowHlMVCBW6zYVZWwdMYRW64zmhRYgtUvQdR0b/nmN4RCyOexJ2fczMMwbUNaCf9RfMaITCOVCpTUpFDziP370QPmYorKwMZuVTwUeGDV2nC1QJnR6aD9t0l/VByY6IsKhn6N2uMZ74dOIQOzPtiLx/@ADlffKVfGCyNxQ277LtK1QDUUPKiciyqP9g0ce@GqIjr/U1eYkEj1Dl5JzFml/LHmKcXsldfIFxlkrwQlxThjF1CVR@iElMJ8hKkDua3SHywglyG5K3obe50@vVB79o9u6ISf0wbyyNCmxHkJXQC8uxHoYEP@s6IHlsIaz6kgdGXfK4BbTujVZAdsJCWr2or6zoMjDF24COHNtZARWQGcLFKMsh1BZEjEfINXQrJEbqLt5SGyHDXkwu4UAGY@h47LjQMzjTmdNMAjVZhLp8BTwRjhVJmd1bHlphyIjjgD/BURASjC0daAG7GPZU0Kx04BTAxLiCDDzP4TlGCky9nmD55Tsj1s@JCcZS2zZQOdPdOQcC1YPhGTKaM9N1gQ2e4iDBx6BgMJGJTmFM0Hs95KyIDur3VzOXkaL3ph1zdlUL76Kn/NITTnWX9VEBd0HogE6UiPe9eLJK/pQyEiQqzniiUFJ@FyEiRZKhyRN90OlhkHgAjOZobncT4lIXE9NMnE76JTEJDkzIZTT2MagKV0uH6gMSzegE@jW9VdkAhm9JgruEflQSDFBkDNBdkDOgE4KWWS73Ojq7AO7hMmm2x1WRQCVR5VyYl2H3wrx8RGBZovWVeRae2yWHFBnVsAYYnWpOg8QSAt8RE5RQBA9F8cdW9CBpj4eRXMM9pzbNw7EEF0WS7DwUfmEASFBhTBA@zK45afviyp07geCyUasBsYE0BWyzl4xqtMGEpQycGiLLJI34mcgT52iCfSORhPpi5EteGhCbgFJrdXY@GbrQ4@j9UoBIgFbBRkoOEOu386fmybR3taFt9MRIIvY6EJrM7kSsCjD4895Quwmr8SWsgtYbR6wi8WJ6An2NeMkXG1T0o7mGh@JvzS9KpIUTWAKfVleiiCf1/RYEvTfvWr5IwF3Q2Tk36kDxT/yJrJARpX2ZIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT3aPH9b8vsgDlY5pV5Y8LKerW@S9idHFIO2jg3tPd5/@YnsFDMvsVK56KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2JhwOY4o@MFMcmYRUWnehcFlFqDz8OknV1ECkhCig3IAN/6uiDQ8DghdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDLMEkQl0kHLIAZOrDoGK4H5Xkyff0aG@9qoca@P5bMmuocQOCpHNhBOhkDrwhgQVCnz0dESgtSqGnjQsPCFY0ZlOcjlJqvFoZE6QjJfHT4YP9pjcD682oSRVG8CchSutuTgeatKajgq@IA@wNXl6XkRcFRnqayrkRwt7uE4EXbsjXwAQDqOrLDJGsUVM0bQtn3rtaNfKVuSAH0ThCuypVReaj7vgWNlAOHuC6qvKtGUQpYDFah18oRKwxdHra6@bxRzJWjw1Z3kWcvCpQWBWAcCORGF4JOPAl95IUU6YvVfvGPHl0ruEdCJKgCUlAyz2Iy5eVZAmovksninrIHGppjGfLnxPFEJiYVJR6sC8hdj5TPSPz9mTlJZJL8qSYhLuS@u3ug3Q8i@1PWNJNBSgPq4jgyuX1c3@t6QCO2YzkDh21BGi4dBhmC2LS2mrsDx77WQjp6YlVjuEQI/BcnbvQxjDXma1IcKVVUXeWLjbrtnQGXVgtZRBJhiEApFF9@qZ/qgK5FvY8OvtyHQUTNZzKhO0MXoCCShtCFrm7ElzyYBBnJfnlWVjBcLrzW24MAKbJeh5X2GV2YcHcRvNKTOKasrIy/skgfO9cw/tKZXyEt8OGkBY4Iyg4@ffLo4NP9x7tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC4A4yK8DspA85HjD3rrFuyZWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyL8AaquELrYmPnaEd95JXK3OGodJLu8tJ6DF2Ph7VTwiKds9CZcTlq9U4niP9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedl1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQoojDc3eAo@uQWiw5xmEHVr5IDyQmveyBpYgoOnWSvLHAxBF8aFccNNyiEFU22UHmgIoCsrYd2IAdMb4NZ/Bu0kctL@QNVKnK7VjJZTxCDaUveHuBt9A1SnBIxWgIrklVfWvNO8w@bApRHSVSAxJm/RJIfHcCywGAiSNGuKen6AHOIWOF@KvIJw9GqKs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpk@5QmjgSwJOcPs0bRKiw73V1uy9v@Y6gsCD3fQhVzTaeN5t2CwT05h0qG647N@athtpKVtn1JFt@/GQVqHepeki7gQfQLjmBNOnJ1vCznn6dnfV06l09pkxGY3/Mkcbs8S4IUq8d4Nc9I9r3MIESDVS2luIqGPmNsmJCyMKkAt4QUwp0KBhpgfQULJcEQi@Kh0A5wLciCdhiNoPXg@/viPARVLqR7k0n7tEaCco1OFvqjQGJNNncRS7t4fzgBEbHkPKRS0PjIpNmZ0Yc59F1j89WQiJ/jT9ID7paCIFm5cMZaTvc1QBEQKlIPQfOAXSF06bDxSwjKv1AaZAhlQknH0CCsGn1YAB8BhLziuzyivCcyGe5Sie2c2YjtI7BSlLHnPDJfmfq4lq32YvWDaJnNR4HoFHlInydFsU7RpfPsvLEVAtQAnU2MkYOTiWAdEWswKAq6HxBHXVBD2esoVtlJFwxBPgSu7sHXKxr8PkiaYRKFJDUPotPXGVX@lLRpddAzTfIVlj5SBP7jX4cIGB5ewPNkvgzoCSdOCOK9DnNt2DgvUDcFXDFEGoMFCbqNWds2Fd1Pq4RJpJV2oYQj/NFoPP4xsZGvBKvx9Pg2gHXNrp20JUC1w65JHJhPBldlCJNLgxtUAr0a8UvGwHkWbKFNDBDyeG1OU7ojUol20rrDdV/avhMQlMA5iG2hA@AE0/WauhMJsX6Ga7ZgPweqfse0s5R1zXHPgo@BoGAv/s4yBISQL1Had41qqib3oyRUc0FpdFAETPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpTJ6t6DfRDYF6TxEgeuM50DIJbI1eRgLclG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkZ5MflhKpnSO60TcAJpKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQTn6JmgZlpWIy@clyL@TbCVTcUibjKeBLdficcALLTh6VGmcEeBE9MCcASqhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb80xsO5G40QzrqBlI0z6Iu9KrilB7l4lEu@5umjAt2Sph/IvTweCLc4eYfy0njOubvAS9pUlnZGBePuqdQfORNd@UwGpUmODJfxjbgiSTASUgiHRNV@bHrYhXXbcKZedKZx5QQo5g6@x8MpMMtge1oaqMocC0Z36LD45l2AzsL1HhxKcOlK4gtgAYBeV4YfMlGUSnCxBKQL2lBkAl@krVg0K6NSITjrCebm84XxKznMrUppWAYzMge24xoSoARSCLR7ivbkCfVgXfqAZr6urUv4oTSkoeJtGsARH1iOTrjl7DqyHjQeRdKDfg5Jnho9wQL@0Qf2KPO2cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNogJ9bC1hr5AYrjjXvyZAZJhQQOuNFArt2B0HnGepqmFbr5fiUIQ6oAZA@hkVArtUHFDYIkFQKTfiPv82mhQEf/9PD@Pp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U5Epfb3pq2IM02wd6Mm1nZAIagvSvT6ynjjPhWj68rJuZ4UqzOZpaOs35XJ2WuTFd1@k4Fk0F3ZR0EX/qerql80moIHT3s8cg6z87PqrJlUgkRT8d3Zg3zkOuzpbj8yC65kjrrcHykMcJU9zMizhuBbs@kc34AQUMmPp7PqGNAv8i@gddCtdQfP8S@o9wvyfIyv4sAr2Gnn7EMkXEPaC44c33PFczl@i/VgcL46kUjwuOi9Keqxr5n076/SXvLHmfSMiarIV3jrz5XtAlHTFapDyPhBtDl@JEARUoTrg/dG28IsXju1vkcGXxcbgJYWhYwdLiU5BYcPkMBn0L5SpQWlBE53s4DZCwx7hKQqwb195YF4RQ79p8BnS2scRjC7EN6kAwuCko0gibCvPnvqvUhWzHX7P0OFt1QOenaZXtOl/lRp3K5eqcwmflN9sAYrteDTbcrYuGOcXjYTSCSmWDFFRNWti/VtVwm4ZHk@0CJakKngLqxEzLSM1Zcb91EVc8QkOfic3m7MOM9gXoJbhbcvOOMjCqtMdpDb6qQUjcl2E7cyaBxIex@MR1dwh8hqVmy6iE9pnafcfqSXyVDAiGcf0KG8jfpBDu4vQ36xqmG2zgpB20PCny18jez2twrzRp/XqEyG7REBB0n3N2cZI@vWANGPJOZW9smZMWu5QnTnvo75Syr@4r5TKo6@pzT/D3uNTY7tOPPmtkWhyCMNJx5avEW3EWbE8GwRkEJdxHDi7cqTMxJyQJ0E4EE@urylCoGS2SQPEBBs@gysKM/Bph0S@Mi0Vd@gZoqgkDS@7NR2lmJC/lvqVPJobNaY4vP65HN18n8rOpUfY7/qJDhWVoZQYkUxPDoIhVdnR8f//pUxko10vE93EFpwLdUe8OQUBZV@kAk9HKV9iHvTj7ENMkUW0XoKuB9tH20wNRV4HoQf@A3JF3DAw3AZ5JXHzpgjetd1FCLqH5CML9Vt0J4SgEljCSUCcCVllZ/mc2V7X8claA4lOESUB34k4FcGsm5altvpI9GGhIboUoca6swnhR20wQF9tUk/6GuhEuHYOGRUIj1KDRYNJr4HIQWWStVpXvAYC4qIC5A8SuKFJT0C72mho0fQ28QaQhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM34DO6x@BixCWQXvGymw3E9Tfr3VkXga@Fsg59zNSp6@cvqiwTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TBHTof1Vy/uklndhQSdDVkJTMViRgCXE/OMBPs1SOHF@0HkwGXkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiG4VMYb4zLQPoExPXKgNo/8owFR6YB6q7@RBPtsUxADNWt5pRZDuAivnF6RTqVTMZqOS4emfeLQek/oamdkNY8SYZh6dGJdT4mbUOm2FDUsA4@rrSudN@r06bYiAi17@Avq5EET6r4sDEKkrjylB82tr8h5eRPJUrb@9lQaacHNpFe3xJTKJYrc73TMdVEBCbgvLHiuiAZMCulZk3OyGpw1wKkYGI@AcXHtZVH1q/uP2BLe/X20/vM/f6MH@L/eOkMYKHDmMXS0YejGlpL6axvLT4ovdFvdsHyCfGqZOiGGXLeB7OouVEm3Qsdq0LQIL0kw/I9wScFvcaBNvIHUeAOZ8ZLzFcHguTqTVYtqNrDM7rq4V/Zj8axo@QcUux4hgQtBpkGJiHXxRjBmfAkmomIjG7u9UMGmKUbEzNt9OJ1M@R0E11sb0Rzj76a@6cfM5PWOaih85/oNTe7qJ9OeI41PBqGcWlgRd1F7WgOWQBzwl4Pb6FxdfV5BvhM8eK6LthjalDN63EYVnj31xlKHtPAef6OOMLohB9fi93VRTP/wXuhYjzXTots7UqIPHQjF3w2h4F5TKYI08wqaLb0zRxlk@P5UFu4sAI5T66ZSmeyapeXxeH161CQpfbm8OvVM7nJ8rJojUPh@VonPolGF/R2ut7QqDFfmSLckrRdxrmXmqzYmXIsarmlSGjx8QScwbiRyHJC6U0t3F64bSHxRjmAZYd2MtD9sPDG7DogDY6YWZVULho7IgEEsM9gat8gItxPTLbL9wVyFxuA4iRS6VrMApzvBLaNraOodGBrfqokbYiNEIjvrMNV1zvC3VnwYgmrK76tHtNcrS/UOzEmyupYO4/ja4WBpchAnH28h1DPTM@i2GrEnKws66Vor/Ze7QDDtF53Gu42sPdNyPHZE95sQNHABC/y@mqCjuDR1W6LJ8Kj7Bh4U7HFYNKhuDRyrUBooOtzWtvrU7SPf95/vyuFCDqWqt3CoQPxxbNV/ruXrJ4p7clsD0YFFF/e3Rpw3DLGr2JS/9rK@dqAY4MLd6po9yJQopazwqb41GeOSy5k@D54/x9CxDrXB0DGekzgN0h0mKJfAMXG5iP3z5Ja7ObfeuzGla2CLt1Ui0rgnlgGDFd2vNSnTMup7plAzmXdnUX1rakyNlYrGYeelgcfqb1Ay3r1QGb8am/5MPS4O4NGUMNZrXzN8p1LjOI1vNzIT3TK7xu2izDJTG4P0PUbV@Qk4nqDjeoqBPR0vteqSdmY/vRllw3HQpZ3eUukw5H35UOkWSWlJPvcM@t2oMXENDzeI1fKZTMYXYCIrLksvN2lS2TDtS5PflzImn0XOi7i4yuZGnKvzILREtyCuZUHaOsWeIpfLim3axmSO93fkph3Hsd6npYCp4oFhB7RVibba3tRi18Qd/xAJW0xdeDjh0emvm7Tgo42vWwJ@UGm@qdGjS0Lv1JoSLnqOcEFq@fXm6ZvIAtNtueDhVpwT4ptvrfWypD8bosoluXhjr@MSqtMxLJ0/ZoXcTfDKcvZGeMtMw1@sxcVdvqS7WIqPXWFK4zkgy@yBljI0Rga93iDl6z00keE/1kaaOfhbFzwzjK4y2ze66yKMTeALNt6X1pAjwtLEsUG/muA@P9RTLNxJ6vuu48DBqt9KJB@M9IHBbbbcxCkXExa4m4ardQvn6qmLCt9B04VkC2Mc60kCOtWJMfeC50qAj@ddaNfp6Pbptiudv4tzoO/Q29dtYb0@xNpDZ2gPjSHfNx6@rescQI8TbmPnpqJDqQdD3Mo2Hi9tcY/i03Is613wiayRM0rH6a8s0z4efsWTW@8Fl5@09x@3Tt7pE8470LG21wyNKYxLnjNxxoZEb@uiWjjRw@/reGiwSP3zziDdqOcDRoLnzwv/Vt1yoDuT8Zge7bE19ehGSSU6s3yb3NTnW1NoU6TjDuTXzqgj@56yv2@FlsBXs5iOOekO8dA4p2xj4HS6Q/O2QvuGKpRgyoe/vpPuipgxmXQfvWXLBPS6cxnppRYNP8LHwbpG92eP@LAWOm6QV1bN0NGxbGmsn3Q9PhuKLlbBCeFIb@SHtyt0/L3yampOFkAje5nC6V2@LIGOdWX3d0@slazojMSCDfu7KtZSKQnpKJBLRgYEHnVdtsv73CJdLJvlt3UFitaSShTZl/I@6Pb3/tDsoBmZtwX/Jfpa2rS0cpCzh9OBd51h8un6HohoeFs/bUF7mSNT1jBm6bb/WIdmzVLwkCM82yBzTY0b11TyNy6qUDzVknTHhEcbHtB007VzaJY59vidSf21S3H@XibQxa@uF3LczFcr037D9Iw@XwJB120i4shxcScyyCBSF1fScQYdmTkXvDjjsp0BMHXJYovIQdx1YsvKbUKrmz8cM6UvPjUGOu61fmROcLPmCqogkl21vehW2F@f6p759SnUbB2xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeI/1gdl9uNQQYSF9BPs7PfljifzR63pbnA1ND3c0hY4bJqaQ5DgRI9W1QW9YEfPqvH1orGLRgfgxyJWxV82tO@M5nhabk@umaXVzQrOs/nOd6rhuE9iNhTibjsZTz3@sLgPtmYrOQo9OyN87MwG49ApYKxvq1mT1THVkyhWkMH9QXDjXSeNfmpYzYF@WMgyENhDCUDhfQTj3YHh@ghtyXHsFJVLe77jsiRMdkssr9gra1sgyybTNyc2zOZMJbs4JnlgZPnLgCQXlEd7lu@8LQTpejZFHt8v6i6PJt4zvQHlHztTtGugM7Y1E1QI/V2Mv2H2MJzoctJdyFtXSuo4F3Qsc1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtamImTAEl/ff/wsGaUG2q19mxQa2CNbuNZuGLhCZKYNgth6ProcO9Al7nM7SU9pq/AtaXbRmFOX2PV9Z5W@82QOA8g7K0zA/Kej@0YXlw1vzftT57FjOzAajYFRjp4a/Mz/0kaP1Qkx2SM81Q746d2azRGBXTMIcWlDHxsdaF9r4XqXsYgDvq9P9DVDEc0Nkv4Xum6lFdPqGO5LmvSLuNeptMsFemjMSLdYTzC8D0qTbpeLxDgft9RHllZsvLHj2PxO3DYDD/XxzVwFhgK6vftCuYwb8ZfmBVbqZ8tVPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6urtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxySQvrwbeUjxRh6yUI1Akj3VPVqkX61qLECqs/fYAjTU3a6DK2G@44bdORHDBLew6XBvP9840AHEz4Bj6d2pbyz0tmJZo86IbmsVhkhrPjU6eCqoQ9Y8JvrsemPymSHflEFkR1doACBgV9ipCyzxBLSR5O3D1pIetYxVc0w34tRrl8tps45km0b3tY6zZg7hazE3vRQOdVY@JeeauepIN6JZZEWnk@4re9Ly1jUQaCxDmgxd0PmVyU3T24GZlRXrIdORgYvMy6swa0VXxxtSZZ3V6@khc3UNybf1B7wktPvH5UNpd63kieDh//DexwoMwu1CLjA9Aqzr9hV8KPzUtf3Hu1DgE8eb9M3ZIZQbTwGsYydYrTwkgQfvGejaWlcJaD17avHZh0Fk39WoR@qYRFaYJckidj0xJMM@lcgQ3Ox6jRx@6EvZReu9E6Mn@XYQcKVBehSc/wqj@c8VC6hR3oibPVWFI3ZWyPnbP1ch9yzgDCBvORNp7NFTGXtPDh4dHstjT105Pu0O8XTENTluybCCVspEpqRe6m5kvZNvR@uZ3kS5d6RKe48OZIywBt98RUOCB67MLT3WznsGVlwVfa0WhKHGZLWA@PD48aPU4ogmS@wNXWdkJKPBe0dHaTxp8vHRyuBo6gfQO/rObG3yg31VTa4g32c2rQ6u454rcloH6dgAbRSI8SG3y3KrcNV1xkbveD42PoPBEzm4947ZF9ZW8lP91BxgL2TltYiijsrKciGXjOzMBmXbcMPnuvY8McfILbv0UPhj7XYUlByyiptdLT3ctOJ/VYphGX8nwvslUjPXqTVqR1jRvb9vwVRVXYfnI70P7cryaxtrOcKq9WHLOX2HpWTDV16k0EuaAFVJ5q37yIvSCFi3gjecnvc9wdlZuw3mJgChd2Flhz8z7LluS7SWdZN4UYHUuKntxihfGu@wIBXu8DlFY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8paMj91Ikr29ewe3JXjq4/LmWB99@ow90T00QnJzxGiJjXco8UIyeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV/rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFoZ2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1eNVV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIcHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@3tEzQwVkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtbQRblFBo/kSm30kTHD7Sh8NniVUr9yfCvcMPYVk@uHk5vCSjeE5W7I71oYerKsnFFvAJi/IYzl5TD4kWOdDR15T3cNb8X@45UFuqki5RsqUo5wZ99aOi0s@u71Ij4eXfAfK6n12Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lXXY7aORSfYYjaVfD/e3U@gubW8ZOP6RD/6@Or@zqbEyo8f669UBxGlOVgYBEzSGUzoScT14eYG0AzKvYQ9Mbl@R3XMm@/R2g2IWnnhevRfBHN@fjteXGHgjfpLiKjtfivg56MzOmcfu4dG4hZi@QvfH/XGr/dfJtCycGEQzow@PdwPqOjxStEiOi1J88WTJGw@PTg6PIn6uMZutU3ql2TodcmXIItdPj3NL2W7Xn5@uQNb680YgbgA/Dp9r5SDO7D4@us4SUH0bTkZWEPKxbi9mTJcarOdM6KThysAn8xlto1zZ0kO@i21VmNtd4b2k2MOAbJqQt6e022hZv91eR5XHxhe09gBiEJtwsYQD9Q0vGbPcMCghJVnbUZ2ThfCzVNyj8dC0ZyuDRuvS0C7SxEtvdTfYZUeWc8YehVaF1rEHbTVw/dSw1zGnVYcVpXL2Zikse0WkWtcu/Osl/mNdk9xbJ6gtoPJTroCkqIV0L@3buOGnwvlZXE8OzNgnEnYqlUwufzMoerAY7QgnNtGO5iYdIoa4Fxdswz@4CwFicBTYP6qM5vZMe2rgWWP@JZFJbROyqdXUfJnt4Ed6KqAmJClH9CKjZkFeDbZ57p/CrVTUS7ZRY2JFZP456NBGMbezC3DRQijUiUknKtucQMhmcIaX0Scj2AWjqQfQddR8Bt5kJWrNoOqfcoYibZ4/OXiyf3S8e/zsqJFpXfqnoINK2DbkFtha@DDbE6HuPtpApOFWt@n0vQXZ0ecscMrCC@rF8BM5y1WrLVVtUSlxB9Nsntu2otBBcEW6hPJJIs@NQrFjgheHHdSY2se3AVDhZ7LpaDk0EQctUp7QZhWWWZXxWIfhedP2w69@UYpC8YtjFfzmGGbsG0oGQhw4Ts/P0TPY7VeQ44Pdg0fPnu6zoIALojkze5NhrZzndrS5cQpop75JO@NqLO4niUNb1WrxB3FATFyOswod3Scb1kDnEC3ADh7691NvscQmwQcMxsNGUf7zN5TLuIybvJMQNx4UKg7ZAskToWxsbLBjIBJ2/@nBZ/tPGZZ//z55I4oQBDvGc8N/9uMe/wpEYNcn@NqaO6KxlOyiCFHbAcGB@sWZf8Q5dd3x@m@u0VcX6GR9@LmH8Hs1gkBfAwG6PSOTfFfMtSXJghL/RpxvTS/IiEgosByP6wloGc/12KnpmXiuH8vQR0N1y8SOW5DIOKPMdvGDcvjZOp0@SQJFn9oTbgzKNwkTA0qTQ5aTZptUWP4BEzESMb69AcTeMUDMYp5twqA9qbCXQIk4Z1/hdh8kqR6/liQAXSGXhENzJOI1y3ae0nSVt7/2T5RBlYF7Au7v@O5Z5h68/Yr/1gf3r3L3cwUJ7bolvEVZogVC65V@DXhBQvwj7iPf0bO5rY0F4tBgX8BXmTmCZjolrGN0ngO/S8COF3ASjc@g0YDcoMV8Gxs8P8NtJdB8ZkVRkKRQ9JfphIMx49sNr5jRLOQLOVWBQkqnAUCyez/Ac9QcYDJZgW4inJrj2gsQJ7e3t5mI@r9RK1R5yyqb9vOs@CIs6CbEFc6GWLgGgzSQZJECwup@Mhh8UmoSkyL3iqtxZFw9B0YlCsfRC99tHxEiSwCyOI4MNKQ@w08uTtx5YA62gx8pjHwTZdMHJKkwJpErKQq@dYpPnQmQD3TSxVePuHUK3G7LR0C0s@jxD5GSFVakR/l6z1ocqg4@vuL3NRl5AAeVzVwdTKNtK36OII4QREVcRb6N56w5adothdMmAzL94QpitsH9y8pgDc3yeu9et8GZuGpBE5HF7h7ZDk50PIDKsISmaFlFLSQXVcrlVlbJr5GfDVQHDf1cQHbApoBldA3zpTP2dvf2Dz4@fHJ0zc4kxYxfjQZ8v76dakpyutEKHfFotZab5N4D5ejxvQdBQywKXYhwY2D8fk3Um2qymL9EkIvzMFertqqEV2u3vsSf8xPzV8ub1W4qGiW6Vg418x750p506QGdLLuauVZaha18/qYiLeApEdB7/FjwtaImkueXjdZ2vWnH4tcpYUVHeB6Tt7ATgKvpbW0qSOzXK4cVCz8RfIwfX/OifTG7ui@Km1k0Y4ZWCSbOycLQm@8RCYjUN8gGWKQgK0HUtb3vkMvoC3OEGv@EMbd/FrXuFClwIXMTxiOgjoOvISMXWRhT9e2IDkFBtsyOEFjV4vZEA7OHoSlRbhErkRT8T3LwjBP@95FnlZlMG9ASSeR2BCvNbjJNGsBLCtChUbp7MgUd8Ikz5ibaaaPBfSNwPXWA/d6f8okJg308HUG8Pj2eGrToA5xbgsSAyXhYVC5LAZfwLZPOUmj7FfJroH1Sv@LyqJdPzJLy0Jj1zAHw9kQyDRztQ1VtsdB6KVaarJXacZHabNEKN3bFj/CwdxTt72XCdrYogN7QZdPuGbNE/CyerLQgf/SPn31@Gk@Kq2iJTOn6tmV7V23qhsUvqjdzEn3i987AYO0qblEuX@cS4HcVMLftFnwfqlyWh55A3/uroeR@NHEfgRPEiER/pI9ZYmpzu3gyo9dEM2GnyWCYVOc2N22WSpFCBQ8KkBml7JOLj98J3Z6zhFLDT0KCr2f38PHaHLOGKsstcFMmSbaJ323bA4kLLUUmBdCBIUmFwNaQhEDNgBLxTiJzAoc0GA5x4UHWBVcE02esaG7cQZxQrVn9Dot8h29ZchTL5YrfoMtcscyA@q6zQ1kBsNf4XCDXA3Z9kzmAM1B/ZSG2YOTXOV6M8o3xgjz0be1AcWIRO7mBCR4GsBZWbLtDF3@JfRv6CsgHlcqz4wftUlIRWWizZ@CaPVy74abeQxXP/zgPdFNlKWq8yjW6jzAZWkdsc6NAaKTvAXUY8QpLjUXRcPWr7wvaVNUbqd5P6LcCxMzhAOCfbWwH4NCiZTCpsyJsNbP/2c/wu/JiYlNVT9ruaSqez1ThplbzLM8@3GxK0mYjU7u7qYMWNXk1a4JOrmzl7p8aw37vYKA0RZFlWU5Rts7Pz@MPtp6Yz/OsIPVMrfBqNr/MFrKvZpdZtfTqZKwWGvKrWUss1dInLfbkyRdv2m@S4ux0/kpsJrTY3uGFqOZQ5Y9Vyux8p5CNnZRB/YR8GTthr@E66TP8J/frXsSto7vTBxU2LrJYs4kfhReLoqI04i34J3X/BVxc8W/U5bq803rzJtnQ9clszkzTHHu9HvycIUiQWvKIgb58Bzg9T6CwJj1Jg8JrNOtfn0/IMzbbNQaD6b5e1/DYq3y3XZ2b0weTx19@HlzP8Hr9NJLstf@h2FQqIUmNFfMUlbaej@EnZ//sJxuX6fMn7e0/@@ZIMTbwcYiP71w@RveRmv9wY@PDe/dyubSmadz95Msnv7i7u5u7n84/aeR3clJmY/tP/2RjQ9O2NWWj5XlqK944OflC1DI5Uf6zH8XbT5583fPq2f/zG2/qKt6KcDtlReATcGWZCk68l@Cnooz1rlfsdQyoXI3N6a8dC/zPN5ha3yn@l@8dvopNYnVN@dyF5yT2KlYoxbgTHPCWDd5OY/XYNkYrXMbmSq1WA2fxv/xbSF//GOBgyHwbbvV8AKswj9WlGiW5iNUL4FA1DfL9v7/xjUgJOZuokRgXXHdZAy4xV9TEnRZcW3RtC2gLUcooShDPngwnhsPU0h31Dr6Y8AIP20Cj8sakGcOPbrPDu4w9baRSqZbcluCSn9MkkaKqWlNV7wA7kD7cqtWkLcatPWaz@TtosTpJU1oDB0ZM487n/xBXbJVn9ecG91SIFTbuvrhfr0OdsvXsVj1Fl9@RqE8VS6Lj3BVZmr2IgwrSaL14xLiJ2rqYKWliOp2@26b3GeJKmoWUhBe/x2KhD3ZZdtVvKQlE8X1j7x8vto/Xn/9vf/79P/8e/X2ffv8BjUXaPbOvbEGkU@gSdbjuVirdel2su@J5E9/rQEeZSqlSUtqXzcQWcKDWU6ZmPrqI57PxI/5BbJWxZpJSw0XZ1v3s8b0eW3jXuU896ucH8MjkwfxakGMJa@QOsXYtHgyt/rZaqXFab0koENWkhlrItySeqh5cZda4C80kasWy2Kpree2Q3W3P@MWGmx5zYqAZFgI8@uWtL@pWD0MWb/WoV6weJKsv4rxvvLC8QqzRUFoGDQiBH7u7UdkoVQoVTWnX119AmtFXimoYxhMvdhoLL47Z2AKhsZA0r/oFTRG@sICC2fvEA8noXZgvtVK2oIpV36W1mVgFItGykjZoixlVDHsbzu/DtQF/9A9X@Ir3DfLxvSnK9WuDVdQtLavkPyzsazi@3nJFyyrAOMG6nU7ndbcDUoeud/Surk70qT7T5/qkM@3MOpPutMuwyyzP6GedvFNyZowToCzFsnl1M3aHiPpNY4M95VyoxVLB1Uzdej2T5bbvJIeDP0lyZjEh9g9w1VVNZVswPmXgBkIZOUFnxj9VFVgMBK3z1putxpst6KD11DYxx1Zd8ksJD7l9t5WSLi8b4K5W/f/teuis0sVdULnWZSq1/bwO0sfzeiMFIJ/7IGWJEVC5XW9tU0iYmZ@bH7zdAvlFSm03tmvOHv1k6iBSPOfEC87dFgDeXirs3bspGVx3AUB9E/pjMpXalKQNHBsb/lgBkVv1VFArLEMCpIXz85/zB4oe9OLL7cv6ZWP78nJ7G/636X7pP8H3cvvaPz0W15o4i/AWspZmQ6k3labPLFrwLit19JGVJjjq8IR4jaxWajXQAZfc@m/zX04v7qEPFrklQ6mF2BbbiqHpwmxsS4i9ePvV/4K/5tuvfh/lRQZ/RkWInWO3VrZQ2yxzpRNuzH5ss8f8ssGNv@AVfdDjcR09bX6zcUFKUV7IrMLn/BNqqZCUcQBuO/02WkOQ2QuIeo33MVErFcR2Sp1rLLYtForE7n7h2hWPx//RC61cjPOJGjzO/8LzvMeRUi7KCZGrWkaV1Is6t1jPPy7yC6uuf/QL6y4hdlFmRgXw0/UYx4wQA0KKKYokwYhV3x7hhm9cK5FQLT2tfSE925VwHkWf0EpYl88R1A72a@VynS/zbD6hbrN1fwvuKvzvb0A9WLMPcZv9WncEEnCzn81rTbRvHpM6r/Dv0Wv8Y8dd/Hv6Cv/Y8Wv8ezrBP/a4g3/Hr/Bvt4N/xyP8u/cK/x6/xr9nA/xrfi2bVavi5jmhJqWW1cvNmUgoqsZ26s2vTdx5xTLshtlr@Z/uyebKLBlrfs2Y4QfcK9yzH//pd7/5zXitFpfi9EGUnOq4TE1WAftQIy9evRsXYjW2qW6qGSvTzagdtQMOk2VclhlmhmoPFJW2yjIGy8wzc5YZOWoPXAb8ZcBlZvosM2AZO2NDRAgF16SdmaCrD48B/PUBkAt/Ju5f7KiZLoOMLBTa6FuKCB5cF@2m0GBxJr4wQNeUVTkjF8wWfoGmIb540VS2Wlq5xGQkKrndeNGMt8SmiFbJtXKOdebGRvOFCENzRuTEhz4s5nmgwFZjSrOpcDQBBgiLl5ft9v6n99ttBYeh5mPncPF/eDiKvt74Pzp0Hh86Iwf@Dw8PoesY9dTdFDDou3drwLD9x06sXt1pVojtB6w/pmzvNOtZCd2FFHBzDf1S73ktIMKzvtEU4mcJ1D3OUP2ofn5WPa2S@yx4BUe7uogQROMO/wnXGQxxgTpyBtfpGTroDZ1nnzdDF3con5@B1@cM9K7wHxS86Ot/hX/zv63/x89YkiUarWTi/HI7QVcS/5LJ88vzS/9eTyYS/ktiG/7QA94xyfllHZ0U6RxcjUSylby85H5wTyS3OcA6ZLNdp7SLeDAsxMIsKVt@S/zXfULW/tWMV0Hu5bp1PkP9KCZWmb7YV9NszjKZZLUTfHABV4n1C9q8kKzS1/Y2Ow219ac/oo9q7CQpUj5XrapbjL9oOa1azQVvxVK1WgpeNhOJ8vWrntlRC6B/5HLJZLUKLzsB2Ay8QtoGe5NiNdaEe@vOHZ5JSbu4CGBmc4VURs1g6iCnPGRreHrXZ7jnB4f0PQpgNfkYfgiGs5JEhr5mg19Mi4sV8c6dhP8l9p3d5J07WjlzcRH6jMfgpS55tds902230T97cSG2RdoHU87De6Z0caFmyik1nnTcxKf4qT3IKiGp7EOtTrmWgY1ruSIE@wXIb28XcvV6IQc@hVI8iWvqDSx@C8obF@NVMXZOdVBLRc4BxSp6R/cHQV/GQYGdX8aoQVkun0wAI02CDHgZwz8XeS4fbvL5JGDmUuQx1XKZR02yXCFRSpX9v9oGaOUg5PA/lNSyqdxWcesuyLz4581WXciTq@dGTb2snRsVnFW/rHb9jxajTQfjzp1sGVBUylSbQrt9f/d4t92uiaKIghLc0JO4u4CmLtx4g2qeL7c4RirVu9TMainPoD15HCkOIwQrAdIVbSuvlhBJgtlHky2AEoFrSxtsQ9DoiTehzDG3AZ6gzkDmPbhYj3XYAC82QOWNmcyii1mMh9O92w0jOfzyQ8NXSkv6XeBjhJfg98IsJ1EYxJ882t3bP05r2xKLaQ9299La0bN7MRVf84t3Cs7i@9P93fuHzyDBk0f7u0f7Hx18tv/sCfh77GxxBUzfvy@eUdeK9zP2ufDSfa0bhm5MDaN9Np2evWIvTbNtQmNaU6iUM3CZZ7ShLmN9Ua8q/Lqmp798qbtjutjbH3777Q//u7e/8923v/Ptt7/z/Z9@9f1vw@/H8Psuf37335TzeP/pV//sd9/@9u@A53@A3x/B7yc//eo3vsF/9P7H8PtPEb8/9n@RePwnAKxf@elX3/vRT7/61R/A71/6vx9c//3aT1b/vv@t9T9M973fvTnOd/8t/H6Pwwrifve3uR8@r8X/bR7vV3/w9l/8O/7/p/4fOn/n7b/4Y7z5L//0B3/6n95@899rWulP//Xbb33v7be@@fZb33n7rX@svf2Nf61morffffv9P/irP/y9v/rD/5H@f0z333uX/7c/@Kd/8b/@xf/@F3/o/34Cv38Hrp/8xb@HrvK3f/BD/P/eH/ztH/0Q///nf/W3f/Drf/sr/xM5fpM7/p9/@W/4/a9/7T/@zW99569@8o2/@fWf/M1v/sFf/R@/@n/9xn/86//@9//6n3wTPX/zJ3/1R7/yl9/89l9@65//5Te/WnP/9o33r97B/6t/AJ93L@e7wHmXer2vz1c/V3n@PthY5AJ0AtT9y29/45eAwP8FY2@//WM8DQW/Nf8/1lSK82P@9v8Bh3a9zhiSARf8fv3tt7@LKPofAEXwH@LrO@HLUgh/@c7iBdD6WysS/fJPv/rnP6K3mFGp06oNjt0lrZTaAv1mq1z2x29/QQeS/NIytBCAn9N3kEMthX0HedvbH37j7Y/@8dsf/ubbH/4KDt5SrpzeTUvqLathEDH/DvEwYuFd4mHELzD/FE2xSakv4I194Qd@8cUXQvtCwWN3dy/A9wvy4hfjQXgszw8KwtAfz@mxCxZ1@86M79z0fcOcGWu8eNHC9Vbww9xTJHtsBaJRPstmKb9gM8aXddAfIs22yDnDO/li8EzA2@J/4ZwJLDXzp3vhmVo4yeGn87PgTiEP2aRm4WISyWqMS0db3IfWiSnfXJlhDWaz1AyUYHBADikIugfieK2WwoQ1Xh545UWrlxgVJZWqQb0xNU@TbpcQxOweQYGUtdRT1t6qzXjCFMKrB@hICej1VFQ1MVWq3YcMa7P7DGEhcAL74kWtXqrN6gjuDcdHapa6R2VCYLXUrP4G3msEE9IJsftvoCilWipVL2GGWEnePOk2b6Q8VY7qnmIpvw3gidv9d@4y9qGolkS@SLCBCOOx8Z5axMaIEB3Cm6ktvzr0Hzjpt0UI36Cs/FwYD98h2XSHi6sYAeBKkizLDH64/r7D7kLwjINKUbbwSHEIKaIIooDQg@H8UEpIUfum6AXyj9W23vtCYFiZzc1NIVYXs@KhTKhTFOaeVOjsA24HRPWiwsRCWURvgw6CBGWB9FXKfzOOC2txxgGzD1P8d/fuFvsQqknPhZ/ApFTWyTkxDmU7lRI1gF93UsJzUEsEoFMCdCHIsxot5KWEdJoxuRbDMHZ4eOgXgjye14QUkLmWVfEdl5Om02kMUshyWk6n/adMT/KQfYdMof5T3kTk0reomablqqA9VRl6saiqo4IKjJ5v3ryBVqH9VZUDUD6Zv9VKy5UoEDy49RHLmgcHhrRcWeCaOVMLOcYSNMUKV5IlBZZgW0mB78rnhQiuRFwrleIUD7AvJ7aCnXcFlcgBp1djdSxocHGVsJRPBoF7h2zv8PHj/U@Px60WEwz6trbRHrtO1/C8BIbtfnqfn8jQyoVkrNFA0McVDRmMsF/JEDM@uP/04KjCeKX9JkhQwaq0rupXs6wKsfH48@2Yv/NIxM/DOeIR3iuLuiW0chaSxupCrGugZoEL5qgAV1lVeOwN7jkz0OnTophWC6jZJWlSmQm/6EwZGi/llk6gT@E5DXl7mzAg1M8lWrpAJ7RWQajX/T17TBXqR/vHkOD4kKlaRhbqX7CZjBlKl0LdqlmGPZgMN3Hzm9jMiJE6bTYyafzTslm4q7lCWs0XWxsb1rmEeTap2c5xF@MlvJ5LWI0P4GLCBwL7ALzggjxwayLz94UeHFb9zXloJizBd@iJah66WVLAeWwOThhHrypQ9/JCkBDb@PLLCavXQb@WDh4IMeAWQxbsT5PMnjyUqZl7U9eg0AFjPfMzE7/7J/dMb2zpc@g6gI3Y5eVlHyAdPGBaXaNXnqKH98su@XTAfTnThZhdqdTeqLmioJ1UKm@ymiaAh7Cl4Aa4DSAA2kewpfC/qgeZZLMlBTiVKorwyGazAs4dC0LFEBjtFXmTqdUkToPZnEpbRQT8lIQ@q2nh5cedfbiIm83wuBgCAWwwcVkmCCvyMP@tINAbIA13x9GHi6t@58zcuZPFSYxsLhPOVlCN2SW0zWY2l0WMC///hQew@GrO9riezajbyhicOjhz24oOzg4489tKB5wmOMvbignOaT2rZraVaV1gwjY3FMrQDklNnBgztEvM/cS6Z1h9Gc8W1UTKQBO3fcPb9SBhvVfrOV366ni1J5v49Xc8NcwT5HJi1bHRhF0NjVnQOWuWSJ4Lg9oZnW0WjNpARqsorq1bQk/uOL257E3mFp7SsRy3FgdxMB4ELKAbIIfg3NdONpurNFhLHjvjHUHLF1MNNQMDCP7UUlpLbxg7xWKlJ3ctQ3d38pV8Kd3DA0D@EtdOPlMZyF88fvRwMhk/NehU0E6uDAnQjhha/NkpVfL5VqMhiqkGZdPCbyZz9iRtbECfNvSeBE9cAPMkrdSCxD3TrdXi8Z2sqklqJZspXQoLxCHOsYZ1AZOmsGZpxPu5zwEqtmMDs6mk9bR5Tlio9Pv9y63z1OJF0M8l/gb4uZT0dOc8fK1KkXgVNk1L5iIQfPQ@oPvcX9uriFq@JFYb1cV7sSBWW5fC3ZHRM3U8DNTMnF9PVQCmzKHGIKMmEy4rruNMKh2j77jGImJWLQQReYGuR8iJl2F2zQzmeH49u0Ik0uz8OpRcXrwMUwXFEi4vAe8c2YB23wpsnTbNNtRyrrUPLAjIZzswEIvRYs@fC7Gtp59l63Vo6vNcUcvlc3ktWyjkixqMN@VcIV@CzpYpZPKaBlBy5VK5eAl0rShvYvT9N7Z3HtB7hSzgJ/QKN@HYaLHkm09N67yUlXg5Esnq5WXsjRD78OlnGgyQa68EDLqfaVK9ls2XwZVFl5aFAjNB0yQtK2VVSc3i/y0ODf/fPb4G/xreIVVWE47RrsunMGzCUG@zR2gfYuKwYwe/EDRg94zumhh7Q512NO@5juf9PeLc0@0THnTf5MZUw6CHOn4mzRuZk@GaGM/GIzQJY7j/YBD2Rx0oILJDHuEe3FzLcVZFKLJnT9bU8nFovhyQwe2XQ/SnBx89PI48j/d39x4KBXbv8NP7Vx55P1KePdp/cBy@FnlokDQfgvjF/UePrr76j9zhs6f9qePiT3hw@Cy3uIVeeGBWyMG1HCn0JiD@DV9JsASJAhSxfDFwqAIes7gDyvEd35kvLJwZdH7OTwObXrjtnx8MrwjHwRFhnSGn7Risyy3/oLZOVvl8WV4tlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlo7ffO9vgOdQx@OOBgq0loWUiFmfOa7VOzN7xobwGE9WllX8vjYWQngIQEbTLll0AGEGbbz28GvsuCzVsaYGm47ZWk94oBc6XXMwhDH4zAkiCB1dZ/B73wvSG9FrcrPHhOdBftdCrOvRhZgginui@FCf6LFS1ctUKnfuqE9csZwVx4BIb2Dsz4Bi2TPoQbo7T5fEiSw@YO0BLmpYzjgG@kcDpPWy1mjt5LR6KZPP/vVv/fjv/uTXBzV1q5nZy2zvPH6UrwBTA/mVkYjqi7EyKTRauZQvlbNaKV0ql3J5tZDPp1UtDbpgsQzqQEYtqYVSvqymS7kyyB@5MoTmy0VfCFYCqVfZqgBYu4tfet4mnUgegvLDFyDZ64SeZDE9fJ8y0YA0ooDq54QOjW@ZNRg6mZph2SIDiDrrstiDB3uZBw9E8R6@4AaOvYwo9vAlX8pkivdE0aCQvRLKUqLD05TQZp444S@ZzD3A75QDQHPzojjEl/0CTqSJookve7sPHmA@fXzRMD1EO@Eh/MUKXooQzcYXkM0JwKsQGkTb5fnkqKD7@IJZYsgDHrIHYaL4UVAcDHnKo3EAD4Oa7u6K4gF/2d3FkD2qdp4X9BN82aVLFF14AaIXxQE4Bi50N1HsgBNJXxS74OrOdfDDr2qjRXJ7oovinKMHESSKM4qtd09EsR34Yzaf@aXJI3Yr9KLyWt@llzL@iaIWFBqjZcOXrCjmwpcc1O3hw8/04aRnDPg1d/mzCzV9@DCrm7Pp/oPORx91BoOOO9/d/@gpBu3tPQQ5ZD51O4OOn7DThsuBVHsPNf1kNL96Qa0P2u2Kbq0M@qTdzun2laD2vG1gCSHVKyiZfw0wo1F7D4L2Hrbv6qsWkAlgG3v9CJ4dvO6N4HlP7/Cg4KIges46HbGK5K8ozYSAmgIu/WJ3PAEuaqdHetd1qvg@q7FMGoWVeaOQaVUpgI1A4s9ULzG8n8C7jrM@yfN5Y1bLtGqzWlHjO5D6CbE50/KmmN4Y7ajlfGVD31G1XGpWQbsVTj/O4pK6wxLqna3XLPFpckcD6V9s7uxIYkNt7WhqqVIoPt@aimKygvedbLHyOpGJZxjDW7JRbO0U85EUxWJKV7RKsQgyGOBkAkN5Bydj2onEmaGfJJNYWpoagCpQXdmc6mlW@4lZelbj5WLzZHVWU6vcEi/LXAPWQ7Pv0@7EcTnIAYCb7WQquPaeENVySYQCKEoimQyZHmjqwmLz5@dfPz45Pv6ChL26P2vxhH@nvuq/fvRwTz44DN7QYLv8AGVQx5X3kGsthXBhNPA6Bu1DfgjDJ2hygR@eD3QdS96nPXMgyAYBgQki2TeeKh8/XIJzNHTOeM5oXqFKFvjsrsHQnr3ZY3qtDi69xxJUKqYnz2jgbtfrtXZtRBYIoIpBqk8YGXtfgDnweNlDow@U/BzPzPkB7VrmstqpzWIzgNOuMUl9MXJ6L7RUt9pDM/b3avcwcbUNz07VqBmu67gi6NFitb9j16a2p/eNJ4aL5kwODjdBjMCDdIk@M5KbrLmPsfdQR7mU6i6zFyX7dDpK6FK9k1z2whm50AORk/h6UOlzOtuJuzMuq/0aSzyHqK/g3d1kiZ58L7mTqwKe7rF2ErwyL/ov@kxjhVyVdIwEwoKuRPjBeussWat/Ag8O@6RSgdL4DX0CUDEzAGz2KABij83LardmsYTEZixJSMpVB7UGJr/A27Ykii1Jaly0hLokfS7Uob9W5zG95k079AUUlumoWqZQnYGfWsxVh9C8@vNZ1a2Np65RteDVn8jjx1j1KiAVcAdgXl8k3v7SN5LbUr7G/aoE6sICkaMtt2uzqo02FYEwatkaBKQauUwatHe4FdMw5muFtFpIZ9O5tFREXxjw0/k0eIJ2A/JFwkqIjInpzCwjq2nVUNOJzAuz9yKZPkmA0EJIY8n0xNm3pyMGPtBUSJv0Ck9AT0rbskDr6jlM35aIWIFlVLFigPUhG5vpIYJ6augWpUgmJZbdSlibCYyzeTwd7zdalcr@bPx1CEpIr3YKqWIm9TqZrCY2kjXPeCXUq0Id2QvVerwBlOvPcTJvOmpAK4NLLWqVRqODVSxm0tlMFmpnti8G22JdbKUzGwUVmuiSEdtgnG9Ep/1Q4ln4jdsodVsGNJ1a1qqCTHNw2ZImlZX8Vj7D5wF5SmHsszfEJEs0xeDIdiIeL2rxeDJexRWIDdGfcgaeRvwsDtw1fkfdEUEYEytiWcMIC9ZIp3IzQelAHLsUcOKD5UCpPRcuzy@368LXhCM8a7mtPce/4vPHu4f49zXwKsNr6fnjZ4fPDh8ITKFNnnI7Vt2oytV2FV4kuX5XiFUYA07a9O1JKRuMve/20dR2/Tl/NvHcAMAVyE5yg7VoW5dhosbGPkNbBTssDnXQ3VFD07KthlaEsQ@4aRBV09Qqrs/E8GSCXIfG8M6hfNupOh7z@4TN53pKCtT8O4wNUpsCoSd2dQ5gt7Y7eLob7Ezb3Vs9U7A5U3ByugmyOu5ki53HY/FL@BNid@nQocYPHbJYeOwQ11T95ZBsrsCS5WC14mvxu7F4PI7LAhXmvYlRuwXHuD55oQHJxGwn8ABtCWeyYEjL53HuPKa8GHtfaqXs44ND@777wODnhbRSri3WY/iBaAlPR1UrvndebG@cqEAyWTF7ko6xuzHaWS@WS5qocY9qjJ0wNThtBHDAox1XK@n0XSh0c@Niw8F1Ehbu3ntjf/x1xsbxbC7OWLMWm9Vy/rZwtV6X1G0NzbYVWQXGhL5akDIXdU71dQooaBDy9pd@kJttl@Bdy6jwrmn5lFavq1saS8bGb7/6fbTAc77/2e4jFsfZ9b/7kx9pxb/7k39FG9DilzTjrmWLMYiJTrVQjJ2fj8/PL@HiYflYK8YLlSsmwc1Xf9RYXVG1rG3bVVZRdH2rmMppd@2q4sdVi2oy5kkxfx2rmI95F36QlilBULDQRF5iAdsktv/UzGvq3e0dqM5ONqdVN4Ai1PAYKgv/tg2vDO1devzigjF46dZ7g4GpkUtRWOWNxLbfSNvsDS7yvJE22ItaHTcLqHh4NVgE2cLDfLgQGK@nlK04A5WJ1RuX1ctWilZRQKl8bhhbdvMKCTc38DTHsteWDX/Glkd/mCjw8OA1eDO2XnpiYiupKL2eeL1rbBssXwf62FIWR2zZVrA2wv8kqZl8@0u/oWmFv/uTX7toX7S/0EDtLJcLqhb72c@2p/bUM3r1nwGAG4ytBKojSY9oFQUdocrJuOVF008VOuQuaLtTG8VrHj9QQFHlZCCamAPb6JECKpyiOEVN2@b2/noJiraFthjSJJ6Tfa1kVRACOZaL3@6gmyYYbAvNhTZaSeFc@ACDYLRmIMJXhQ8WoMBjBOOz02171tQd02mYBKVTW2l2B5JADh@gKcUNsiHhs3oJeJ6ydT0pL7JHWCPRi40Mz0PDjDBKCR9AEt@msjVnYx3NnWBM04axRcYoVE4K6DUg7xbkbfEEbfJNUO15hDTjpeOJbBDRhQ9A2iAsmCCEMHMbIlSBU30ACIA6JHzAZotts2ySnZupVHVh9fES9@2jXUo9MLUgYDKE1kPTHkHiKsYDL1AN8CueSBd@C4MMGPEMgHAYfJm/BsoFJqc3lOvIFso7gwJYZHcsQVVjd@4sSlWrmb0koxoh/BNzjJNi1A726rICsEAx@7BXEdMM7WlWA9@Q7ADjKSouUJ3EDWlWI0mZiK@XggD/70y0SJFXmooCqlgBv714r@gCyiAxop23YZdt15iqFZMsLHwXyt6lQtGB91DbbM4@lLUvgsBLKOHPYsE3coBpHUcnGn26vWprg4EsPsUPlKDFNc4MfBsZ3KYaMr@DSZA6TAVVMS2K3Tdd0INo/0FgzjGRVZOYbGH@kspBO@u1HMMN7vkkPigVxmbw1NEsoZ/PBplT6jrQoN7YscmOIdlZwtMFQBHAo3wTcLzYU/sMP2jltw0ljpbII/NvSPlYYrLLSF8Cp7S4AaDjgr4c4CbNjIHMuqMe08osQYRGpursEFySElGBOyBOI447ljGCIh0ZBh1J8yqKMgARa9ohe32PTaCr4QMTRiDbU/yPritn5ompHKNlWcnp48k1bv0khlIZdj@@18C3jWc5zgmzzBODzx8nlmzHeAwUCpCJ04DZxQ8QW8FNLFo2jfMaaprHgl8RHkXuLKUjaTcS8@T1Z1bdSLSxRS9ovDFd/KD6qW5H8EvXheBr0t7cC6xPkQ0leJdDlmv4dmdqcbQoERpUEnw7WjUy4STjusQ4IcbEwP4UOoWxa5wy1IkFHGOAaXYDSy7Yi6G2H9AAQH0PehaapZy4FbQ/BCVxe4kudD2fwdvsQ5bVBIzIjYP5hrwABjZ9bRk6hEFSrIc36UHDyDQZj3wFeueoB2Fo@cInP0wfUDe6yWTogrzZhg8OBx3Kq8Z4twhe8pEX7B1Iz1T1DQgsQAlXlGQjIaYAbEpMihx0mP5qck7tAvGSCrsOKc0Qgo9qgEKigo4sB@0ORr48JUDAPd3jnyfwjVaenZ3JZEl16pqy4eHXmDzH1i1lPDBByHaUiTEa@9@9NfF75z7chUviH2GTx8PxzgyF2Vr5zpw/BaHv1fytQIl434vj4HiKHxsajMjqGpo784igHpj0obJuwt@ZxOlPa6XPA/qrIP1JpfglAmEMwczS83Q3DcDSne5Jun/Wq/oBp9QhATi0ohF4on1jN3gZeYHLHPfDGM4E@WgY1LFOaHUXIIl8AniRNa9hEHMevPrvY3MGiWzjjO26rj5PUHgSYyMBJ@Yk9rA5DPsUAk4YZtg5N7Zrzhrz1lLyWZgcBrVwb4OLJtWE85uBcsvLGD7j4TMIn/Hw2SLTINvGrMVFMvS6xOog1aMlziAmgpkHcS65leJFCEEGeRyUJvLDmPMlv0v4dWuUOsA3f4N2rAWEATQxBoQbCaXxvNlotmzPONtqpZQBELtIiIAWB9CNFuH0rBe6EfvWqTV2vCUvGw2wwqjklxu9ukOfGjitYB3DBiLC4Pgy0WbmYORvwuACgV9hgIByGASiaLA7SZjJamjpmwKBcBriAse8YA2/MC2Svvwg3w/EJY56jtgooFYEEPqHVYJiQggLeg7/9l7AHT53HYgTxJXoc2EjtN0Wb8UBk1e6Cuc1VWqkSKkkKSgmoB3F1drVqgTh0BSNK0GRal767R8t/sZ7F78P/WJ16Ylg@YBRFaJdBfc9ggjhdxfCKqvXIu0KJVC2dMtwYeTa5/KpP1pDNltKoGbwfLAK3pk56Q4TkcbvJnn70OlK0RYrISnMazWo4rzGuyXvFwFKOcLDZJ6fbB4Qgp@eMxCAkVmZzPCTzaLJZrUaZxxstibZWaSQMyrkjCfhsWdrCtnyk4H2dBAML9g8LZBOcWOmCPBUPoyCGDQWmaefGrhU/hLtSuKig5/ngucQFfg0hCI20lm3tTL3RqTQEaZ1BQAS4jUAPf4Z34pwleGpUvgW8iiOyoBH8TefDDivAAIjFlzltpcTIZGRDgwCv5iicQD6rphqCKJKE8f4l@E/MR14Bj/1umdmOaa67JlJX/n7B/FsIWYjHTQifaiZHDJk1GSe2b7R0qjMEcMv3g8dkOo6Zw5LrBC2wV@Z@kmVjuV0lJGOW17w457cVx7Pk4H@gEsv7O7YmegTJ5ercKXJJLJblT/XGcyB7eA3gSL210HW6zmGZ8cn0KhdZ2CbnpFmaBrzxPDVDsP/IIQQlZN9p@MJgr/5iquxCJrTFYq67TZ@brzdTuCexmQl3KBNWxyRPONxAfVfcEXSA3vygR6OE07npdGdJG@HiR8T8JMdm92TxOHYD8SZ1F0GPKwL8j@EDkGCYZ6z0BzJUDmK0p1Jgj6CMXRGzgCkvqknC5j6CviDBWwskD4eU1nSTEeVthL5pAT1kkQ3rSf9pJ@8d1L2iZbQk2F6bRnAEjLSzL2KY8SsuyK79trseLIgv6P3L@9RtLxHN5eXtPCrZeaqeY0Hvl/W2cQCAkRcFCN7ezGw6sC3eteKs1SU0BvlKp7gnYvYoy1lPSzpLkTd9aPLfaCPdPjmwVtY8M/W4f/mBgyS779r8@nQ7dnRHPjNCHdnJugzbl6wgpqA6AdJ5D3XswtJ@/475gVx8QuaD1CEADGWGJeNNpahY45B7fbCCeQA8C00j7u4rtE9be2q8cAVZXJP0@xEW99E99s9w9LnRi/hx0xH4AY1fgoKG/Grd6s4Mjpieg7X9RIwdiXDUBjGEek8UmUNyejp02RyPVnxKGZIPTRTTiU8WI8/DL/GmnGKr8Znq0EPiMdjOB17auL053g@nnMz/hb/hpfPR/n4w1sSLUTcjhDAAx891fQi2@RN7PNpIqzSO4wIYVx5ucpoZTuAiIaXrrfh@6Ho9ppC40YS1YJWFpY/YLO6xc2bWjxCFQFN8nWndyPJ24junWkuQmoc2IKF7b3fEHINMm776HYTUYjc58YWc@xrPAH9aJ7OXjOqtFcw1DAlcbqJSeo2yRdJATXjA3jihNNn8ESAA2PS5gQV1A3ntPzPYjIKGenjiNTi@4CQDlAiWOQo94sRiSUEboh@fhnm2V2bZ/dant2lPMMesJxlJJLQXcrSbwVsnpuawDL6kzXcGYNQd4bHTWwbLtvRXZytOI@b8YqZZvHTeAUYctyIV/YTwJTjvXjlPjm8eOWIHCfxyifgWPSt@EW8EnQLjODCKznuor/PwvG9G6/8v91921obyZLuNXqKtIQblSmVJGwwRghbgLC1FgYPB7u9gVYXUgnU1qlV4qC23d/MXOwX2HM/j7BfZd5hrvZTrB1/RGZVliQw7l57r/mmvzaSqjIjIyMjIyMz47CVdb6mRv6nIDTtegtr0ZhSmZfykylCpEC/SWvEFVuvr7s5Gga0sLFS6SpwTOhi@8TnMC7/K9D/kpKKk9XgJc44n3BhtaiKiUXDWjGkHVo2TDKEGTN5Ta/m1f0dNpuKiqCZRdrj2XUYPKnhmYWkMBLE8JZvNOiTEITcXJuNkbJWsgeio1snDuVBTrbP1PNYH2hm@f0JFT6LG@E8ZLq@Ga8kCBnAh@GJynfhOYWOaY4xwp2sMwMtEPXnhXs6hbFO4qJH3x4hPutOFiJsc6aIjBKDtWQ66XB8OYfGBv1Bkkn4LQzz23YdPpSTSQnunajGUkHPzDte82PdMwgGe/I793XHqgfUEiIIL08KZzLLonWBZTFexbLO0lRl8hEKlsyhGR40PnGOt239lcuJuHF5rbhrGTJ1pUmWXEkxSZU9RLy68kfSerR5rSIO1vdtX03NW5y1ZAHAqhm1IvK1/x36e1/0d6NQGyJMNDBLsZ69lE6r1/eushOYd@JmpwcQL1217cxUjqIWYpLT7sDSzO/jtSkVHyYfouRLoxH0CW3fkC3aE3yDbpN7C4EFLWF4nXz4aYkeflq6m1DTGknn2jNKi4eWNBzpeIRp3LX7cZWOzxpivOHzbb/z3QM8TA6wPXiAxx0YTpBcZvnwqsdWLvHcJrEtTyBSi2tKBDlfl0bDHD8kcc9Xt9G1LT3Yrx9s7@/tfqRF9/nz545eo8cxfpi1OGuN1nGBzDbY0XowY9uy5CIREy67cRwfXvaHo0envfSULBFhTcqAT60Y9tNz3NGyzJLnE3OX6klZi6Ia1qd4GvgJqQRVx8eS3dZ0HRFBglH2ia@BGPWW6O3ybs3hlEP1es/vBvU6L18mpa9exTA05kbc@VvmUf4qHHLqWsmXdZNKcegJtb2vPrypHKmjN1W1c7z1V/Vx/1h9qOwdIerAu@PN3dqWon/VvcOqSiVsLZFbEBtKout20AiQMFYtFQrPFEPe6g/GIneyW448P/S76k2/EeCaaj30u68u5YfXC0YbUqtK29ExzjDbnEuy2x7B3oKTH9I2FspNk50J4TSgqOw57Wm72PN2@812q01lU9j7DtpBaPzPVKdNI0jy1rhgu6IkIc8hmw5x/lJYYN1QdZ/K4@6GwPhifwUSo4QkRmx6ShMu@u@7KXhUPXh7qBDAYmt/b7t2VNvfO1Q7@wf0893H2t5romft8OigtnmMV1zw7f52bae2VeEHgkDBU4gs8ctVOLoXBQ/FmSqNT7j59gY0/NGv5Kk3NHh147NbZagWrnqQPm2/0/4taC6UUlch1Be4cvJVgcrOVw5ev6c1XwW/4obTXAWz/UH6OOTcm/MFtc6t0WTZoPlW0tOVlr1c0eH7iO5YIf1OUOKIE1n@7ioDnI14mu1Apbdgo4KzbwlMwXPZgKaGHhFsgDIGK2XFabMWFtx1BrlBrTU6fUQRldbEiFD/QNVXxtSklGKKaVsZAIVbRK2H86BiKXpAfE8PlnSzo6EUUE@jB1JAPZMHUEVrsB1Ry7rE1Wj/CuJZrciDX7qDHb4WVs@jB5s@72JXNU4ybjykvorSDiJMR4eTo8kpDydw5XzfXCXk8kgc1unIxAgkZSXJRLlKZNs2KpkmYdPCVYM2e5NM0HhL3AA7Ib81ClW27HjqCMZBQa8taekuOn5PTKBi0x3mPbWKiEhl7bXdjtK5saPJoM8MiFSSSTyiettaKwweWo9qbk616GsbSU6pakzQvoXA5hQCfwQMAcoldjoNXqnY0xVg@i3NytmwTxyJc9vf7fLEzs2rRpCooK22sr@0f/vN0UR2E/skY6fI2NEQ/RYMSa3kq8xWf0hznMUqJ8CCFGxc9gejtoxhNtkDvnHiZY5KY2Gj1n4ubyRaAx0mW@z1e1aj58TFd7R6Tkz5kFaZ4@XuPBJfcWZk4nxahMXuDuj45/3rwLo7c3GJdBPg@IUUYb4rx@HneMSYiP6ZimXH7woJVVfLG9ubp7nff3aRVVXEgiQ1NkaH@EeMibZoevA9HxssDqF36ZlmsuGFV@eorW3wtLTELDfAaB942aZ93at6KXon5sbTz@GEM/mcH375UpZaOUgmnQk7vMzG0s1VJ6ZJl@ucKW0CYslOQpZkfdY8cRlmJK9fwfEGo4AQPz3IEezbJ3LNaRFiend@1SLJolP@6uGO4Dtqgy0q4nzpcKixxyP/U3azvLjh5GODEmWRM2tEtGsgFx3HMkvh9WoK3Pb94Eh@Pxzc6r3YyfLwXdC274X2XbjlFu@GJcuSBevhYH@/B6wsbn8ILPXdvRuwLJLT0CJOj5jTnc9E1rT3t/jz1Njx3CMwWHtxghIBtVq76vEVtYnJnZUKjg0mVogOj7arBwcqLfsTqktyD1uGphaDgP1IvYutbds9FnZepDRFm@VIeTJPEhZtkYvTPZN5JvHuEBVaB3E1PSJhEUf@brVvRerplYVVCLa@Z4FoKJfE7rORQeGJBvyV9oCEbDxoVgdTM7uZkcWnHdpG4JpurujGtg0/W1jL2o1EusOxDci2CfIv4Fkye/w@iH68ZtoRBQtxkdDhJmnStN7QPuGQGh5QQc9LjuA9w2KGFEb2omBnDO1g@FVIath/nqGYkUQJF13YEutaOdaoiX48b9QcNkjEMuDD0lO/FItmemFEPD9ZtwfUiRe9bHIJIiUTqVVf2VxB1c@@6iWMqRGtk@VIIbfn2jxjc2KwPMPprIZdurvQY9hCr0yKh8mmSNre21Tu79OUrBKJlgzNZ3bGvCTIK8vLT78Fe7IXpnruz8KWNWRSfo66A9rfxyDDccjH@8S5tT3XvI8Z4B7SiWm9mTATFUnVmbGmJPrOi5GNH@Ei50KEDALZI1vtZKuOup3AbTZ0WZFs6Fxkqg/WFI46KrNmivpf728OAvmb7T36/vZksqEQTAe/wir/bX8YBrFXnhUJxnoED/rks2A47HEx8WfqAkqW3ZjudbZjbzsxeJVe4SXft9k9aWnvJDG7dc1ZAzfCx4seElTjdK80ebyXK5bsru7UdqvqCQe2bCXOItPDtGPJnkft3n0IsAzmcwksH@zD9zhco3@Eg2tAEpnYmy/LtHG@iRtThLTmE850pM1CtWwtTo5@K2z4PcQOcdOPQ5V2f6CKfApb3d9xZp2sF0qJ@oRcOOhlqZabznlprkrPcKALSEkQMpp4bi1Y8NQwlpJwr7nowz4KF1vBrZyeseWkny@uFlZepLh3PXfkdk9enLlPGuW0osXX73XDq@FN89NF//K6pTpq8Mv5bWP8269KLT9TT6mtpR8kunBxpZzngK7P6e@qelFgztUIvuRIyUiY7EkmWaUWVLwPLz1SDn/hTfMaPCQmuFQ96RouhIvdqNw9WTkr98qFUvekd1aCk99osTxaLC5m8eAHWkVJxsjN/MnoDGuqfeoa9K4VYnhyxlLtGqLYNYSevPWH7f5uZe914jQOCgCOwLStNx@oS3LqOVizwffE6wU3WX1M5ipwbAoKUmqOvYKKcJDn82QcxzTbhBmNikvabHjLf8dOaq7gXQ1GfX5jIjaCtdSX9pfUnHFjKvCJAhU5aZu4jvAvIDhxmSwuhuTpWKyoc0VR14rwnXQsECeoyeIwfZpOw6cQiGpfrpOzVOgFfuMSSCAb@xeuptbXOTc7sVro8SkeTDn8ITtMFM7wFRcg9DHg2wY0wZp7yG4fKeo@fhfxRZ7wGdWI/WTYQD7FmiLewPxbfWb/Jq6/TgQQws@JzuXpI06teZEiKb6DfLiAcGjJjT@uGeBWKYMyh84CtrRXjoGzpTjTCM1qMtHzuRuQU2hF/@ke5Ir8a6obUXlHijNJ@J5a/wpBSx5SfrWBj05cLWtVy5lqprBFirlvUgMnXbQ9ehvQtBqrraDTIaSFFnMxOfCV/Xt1@4tR@@EJ2jyLkJf3uan3ucR7T94LUnEpjxb4uNCaXSid@RyX@6rScTF3qq2yYuXFo5FueKSSxGVL95UNvVG/3o4Lb0RDKVwZvVhPvMhZb36aMfry5lGiTsTg0fsTea/5e0mPfIRlouyrZPv4TOkBCth4VtuaTHCp12t3XqZ0Im/9BmyWJmoqJdU5QaMyk6qsfTC1OCENDuf8PG03yjGUxaKRODxn0hvrr9KeVjJeZifREC/GqYk1Y45YVOI2F5lwt@ywSO3w60cWCIYJRlNm5m6YymNdeWyBRalHplnxgpya4NS1ySlehl/kF/wxkz2JnCmXmf1yTjC/lc6Ld3OSQCx0H6VnkykpTeAuIg91p@5ZReK2x5MQZwuJPesUOGozEB/sFo7BH0VywhYURlJM0T16oykdFyga9r1rCPHya@pv@Sep1z7p2INOcKsq2Gb47IWVSji4j4JwFCJ6FAe2Ca8Ggw5uHVnhu2EXah1oZGkZ1y0xRGtl91I1WPZIeRfftEM6VfLUPiDfwEAkfhFeXVzAmQwesP0biFacuLRHXqrSG8uBBs2Zp0viZh4oBN9gAdxpX9hIyMjJ7AGlw4HfCLwU6WghaT8p6WqrrdOa8nk6/EYQpIyWtLVU6p@u2o1PW69xn/u8WHhatEh2ra@DC97TZ7GDFRHJvFhCnMHl4rNUyrobbsjdcA4AXbWLhf498WZwHfR6QapCKwYXDElpDYPhddD0UqmDILoEBlywMm4m4Yfdvxo25HCHlC6fmBFewqEr12HEYfjE@izXxQ2@K3NTuLSKb5tpqK/bTRDQeJy0@rgd5gsLhAkQeqBSNxgRUZ44KokS3z1rXFh36eIgiqiBOCfW3UREhl5/1G7QyPBJVqpDoOQaJG6s15zAhNprdHw4B3uzEIB7TEwBg4C5SroPh5S@NP8uHJTumLlj983I5En69Xmu0HQPhm2SvjGBeVS4moU7DfDRm9qhOtzfOfpQOagq@v7uYP99bbu6rTY/8h03Lso5Vq96s79L0iW6TZdb8316kK4cUs00v0hV9j6q6o/vDqqHh2r/QNXevtutETQCf1DZO6pVD11V29vaPd7m23eCoPb2j9Ru7W3tiIod7bvcqqmWiuup/R31tnqw9YZ@VjZru7Wjj9ziTu1oD43hVr@i3lUOjmpbx7uVA/Xu@ODd/mFVoWOp7drh1m6l9ra67VH71Kaqvq/uHanDN5Xd3YmO7n/Yqx4oNhKwerlZJSwrm7SFRUvcz@3aQXXrCB2Kv20R8QjBXVcdvqtu1fCl@mOVulM5@OhqoIfVfzqmQvRSbVfeVl5T51LZb1CFxmXr@KCK@EmgxOHx5uFR7ej4qKpe7@9vM60Pqwfva1vVw5JK7e4fMsGOD6uuQtJFbppgELXoPX3fPD6sMd1qe0e0Zhy/g72DQ4P8gQhDWFao6jYTGGYQ6C0Raf/gI6CCDjwArvrwpkrPD0BTplYFVIBFxdaRXYwaJCIe2d1Ue9XXu7XX1b2tKl7vA8yH2mHVoQGrHaJADQYZH4l1qNFj7jXGifCSr8SsKcO5Lg@nqu2oyvb7GjDXpYkDDmuaW5hsW280zT1E9LUOUdp9nBn4XftgpTX96DpADMvpE5nZZzRRxKSt/e0qrcg62FU6fnFMq87qRCgl@x2tNNFL@pkIWdMMzq8u6u1eqw8f06iaHHx0wwsXqYQc5GE5Td2TUUufr3CFTKZef1@p00b3sF533IfUTKDxrRr6GPy@Uo7uI/I0YOeNg5@1NaH7eoJQGz/oi0421MMFBEoK9X8Q0ze/Gzgqn28Guhqc9wHYHB2Fcm1yiasUEo3s7IgEMnGTfDLBv9uaHbhi1oD3GnWck8Iykgv1Q/rT@xL/kMXBekDSWY678nlsYhmN9m@BaUYa4ZAI/EdHJGi3uEkvDIJPF9mC3Rz2/N5Fv9/MOo6pw2VHtA@8yDrfqH4eXExUz03WZ2T52lmnOAjNvptVmOj@WZNM6XHxhtyzLP7UR/zhGGwk5gNOTbkpPqzWh5bZH6Q6LJJcpUNbwL2CBxk639vKj7UP2M0Vlp6VJp6/iZ7L3IK9IKLd0oJ3wvXO@OPNmRSgCcaxOIgkbR0hI5@36hh7k6jwDRW8RKGbdhOWP7RWXwa8rhNJSJG98jt2m1iNh@1bG3uSw68PKm83j3d2SHQC22ery89XSqko7NaPrnx@RDsckJajjg1oHSc9jV9Zs2SLFB@eKVY88Jj9mYHzeRREjHczaPwQcR4iu42kJRMEGbobIptSDyZ66QB0SCsOwPEoZfh15szUDJBNdNVBb7r@Lav4PulKzAPamKUz5lG7xR/Ajqa/meJRhzQDaRbjEL3EubS7YLmX3jGmory54cA9KOKlDR9LGLeIBnzUxfaz8K7lX5q3rVEMxZQR85WHnWsSEo8msVDGrqInM/sdxxnRB8AcPYye/Kj5jb5@1AHuONydH44qo0Mi405UE@fU8WG07vSJhnyGnBsIqmZaWlc45Xc0Ujz39HFyFBjEmg2MChLIwMY3CbgUxRGZbJItYF8tOOqzcCqCdwBOSXOs/k2cO6s7GkrJxA/Rv01UCiWwoiAnQrWbqI2UKfIximNhyJkg05@iB8P/B9JkBvx12nES9JhaVhDAB1GSoQqtaPvKRGnfmIsG63Yjpqb96GMM5qs9MJdRx/Ttza341xAJ9OiMzYOPHPawlZ1BADA5Djbs@RuZpF36tHV6lXZ0ddyT9BrdQVbptcIsFVNwcytnLqtdrrlbwQ9HOXLWZDW4S1XVK9m4nfOspy3TxFZePQ7TAs4x8T/yT/gAJJrwzKWXYrU6yVkFPcuMHNChlqwFpxlFTCK19Oudt3ZPlBUiMyH79c2XIRSB3gA@0/3k5CN9Jea5yYiLvBKrI46Ch7Dj2CZj8dEh687ZELMTAM7jJh@GID/J6AYLREegc6i@GJrKPmZDETQSWx3GcQYhbh2PSMvL6k2EPZ9MgkMj7I97EvE@kFMtU8KTAB8aQ9td3lNv/TGh3HlYt4XF8k8O@y5sF9GYHEvo@sjF0uj3h6Q6@ug34ei2x46nPuhDh6AXXg11/EJaz9pDfSJhlH5qBmqT7N55mZFQ84xa2B7BW6HpMX9wl7oBLEQlPMltbkVliXkNj26YQ8f27WJRZdfjN@tEEw5LykRcVyvqyxcpJQTVIUMDpmA7jDYXbLPJ7eDeIZp@N/3hJ6z9UIF6zaAZRSa1QPJZoAxSrccxHhsj6fqgH/KJBg0FTkAiShTlIC0yVKU1@rlmJ23XlI6jYyJ2Kffk@9uJmNRYS1FDMePq1on5VnI0mKDSkg4NGgULLS4tMyqzNlxf79yMcbTQ5LW1Sp/2IpGyJkpE@bFRHfFN5Gb07SO@6UP@8uMQs4ee4I5bq6BAGDor7lWn5RzjB5uCD@1g2LTPREmTafoDHL/x1qffY140R4c67F/DH4XBmHYAjXz7Ns8w6tm/9C979a1@x79o99s@7dMQJ/5WJB6@jvkrBuxi2L8JOc0Qv2hahZrj@LvEl5EwbPgd3UuWrNBc4SgYZG0zhdFwXLmUMBF8cg4jwDjFKfP3YDJGWlTn2XJcKZX0P2V7vKJTurPu0@KsynKjDwBawG1MWFCID@mIHZMs59PSVIHz@wpYOJ6rnPKdOyz2Ehi/IBLxNUwCY4PMlFmC3QnszO7E@KR56zY5BuEQgZaC7QCJc8IsP3Z9ZI0mKfISlgJrqrhasKrKLcot4hDiy/huci89/wdjTwj8CfSLT2dxyyxGYBHXMtGWQtmv6CijhAubB7ZZRrMkJinWvmj3LPdDzlJxOwk1@Xp8FzXY8oeUIh1mb4orMSOztPFBNrxsnUROfexgUVlQCw7H7YAKUhllC3czbPAt@1me/LjElZMzCKYtDTlrIX0XqRpEJeTlnTCvtVGWmMrfnjFLSw8dtQkClmeZnFn5obNpo7mwB0pb1ldca/WHJIzTE9TTph4L4ag/WHgg9e6UHTMjs82idcNxvmkILMxWpsXySZNJWx7j67iUmsRngmmSFGNLM@IhbF/5e8Tmk0S8Ldcx38r18TfocBfNYrupaFGJxrspcx@L4jUses1CE00pxh1BSkvR85M6dbx@twTRMGV7VWeJUYfIqI/lqwVqgkwRlR5OIeY@jfsEPZpEObTbJNrZ43MnUSeN5EzIU/MqEeQS9ETgdjhtklwatGB8gTBxouFGQipSOG/dMV/lFXPnCDKMFwIQWnGQi8@h5AQ3HqwJPuLsAK1sHdZCRUgi@rZhWzhEQf8jgnFUfn24oy0e6uNc8awkkG4jSLSr4FL3QTL@5vTzpH7LUKZIQVN8BimiHk3JpsuH9@rP9oXKEQSpza@1pW/BRWcctUjY0B/7Vf0WOnDclK6ZmFHJiVBn0UBzgXYpF51AtqvQ/tpD4XhYN@hpRBsIeZzFx6KugXDeK4WI2qhy2xyjiKPJLbPNUbkNqRIzlPwG@fVUFFWXN64EIBCMqX65SBAQ1pSxx6UAh96xOS@BqB4jqlguYlrSQ46KGtt5zngPouoCz5atEoVZJV7YMHIzgZBiMbtMjAjpLLOLxFBooZuJi1Xi@ez@xCVIITa8LxSnodCjkqRhNHJCQE5IXXBiiXJSVG5BczC/fLbsJF5G/M1vXxSst4XJt0SfCMOTXHHy7Woh8TbR7NJSsmqiJtHDsVtNvCRSODbCkVT4c/@xa4od8jyyCbU2GQktQ9tnI2E47TJp3@b9Eqp1dso2OoaBZ3uGm@1XXVKsJIKy3x@AXS3wlQFit//p3hrLVIOJzhXAcemMs0tWNoSssaax1KNb2OmaSHtRgAKzp@231PujnZ1E2NfzsTE06gbD5UKhACY@t4PfG9tqHCW1@/lk6XzrqtPJD27@Mnx/nmfZHwScEmDN7KADGhKaFKHXH15IZgjgQEVROqcdWbHXv2q17BQMuKHE4NGwSUkdDUHxAtSOjF7eH/EBEIPUC@zP6CD697OKZt@NL4qmhmKuoag2TIKv0@b2jMiDBy3YZ0c3VQwMgtlYM9G65ZQ3PmMFQWYTHiwOX@x8js2T02@CTqfvqg9IVIxIAXNfJyvs7NgVClIEN4zs3XsVcjxaVwXX7Y7lV4wiNq8DnFmYTJ4JExcesfEPgovq7SCbPvkpTcsKdXkR3VxEfGpXpS/Sjg4W/wCwwoeE9oNKd/1BtsF0mixMS72ewfE3wuhp0Z2590kUcfhMTNPs26VB1NnoehysgbrusC5gYtnz8HJP7igeETd9eltsgYYFgaFxQsyVh9WAq9k/Tixej1qth0lFTgMgA/tdElEyofw5gch3ADwD9fQjeiKK9l9zNK13JgKKiIKDZB3TcgcV6qiQSj1ulH@9yVYqFTU/WFxUlcomfcnlVGWzorbxYHNTbdPvTfz@oby0vFwSmbvtfKaHm@bhV7VJMPiEc7FxOdymn/SuDL8xWGtjiOfz5Xm3NF8vr2@UwvxJZRNu/fTtP//lf/7nv/6vfEX/@Hf82OQfJz9FhTzPy883Ps//8LWE3yfbZwvz5yfzg7OFixK47G8cNbxfG@X82HzUG56nMrIKWE/ZjtTsszn6jK6qTJrArj/8RNJlTWUaYT6jn4aSOYplbKYRWM8D@FGe0xbeJB2Y3MoTEhkCOsZxPI1OI4ABHq03REnCBXagUl/uVszBPcLBRAWiW5WMjsTDOut1AJ@WOJICfHFpxcq1e2HQwwn4Neu80r1UyqfP9qiu@Tf/09vwYrN/q56cZtWTgnriqifpNH8UV17QU2c@34Z3rhSj7UA67dKb@GoBZoYqbLOix/sHzrUzQe5Uap5T9gCSCVPBhcULzo12f@wsIwnXwovUHHJ1Kjki4UsmVMl8nu99pWH5TCW@phOuNqwo1PUuhhuzblSi8YUK5IdiCBC33BWCrPWpSdz0sUcyvuXNEz3WKc4mxIBB1oPXOzzv8YDWovmetnlO7KWQ5ojN5@Up1saSOEMz2ngj7ccI8IWKbCcL7Em4kFlIiZW31Uvupnhh2/3TzCe2DuNgZGzTpdLvymICsea2CTff034t2pBbrldUuh1dr1hNpSdtv1XKqtK96ozaA@2uwK1jQn2OWvsqMwkjyoAEjsTsX5ueYXxQYCJFTQyLJMsaq2YfXZeZ0NOu6TTAjic3RxYR8j9laW5/mZjbTp69RAw7CA8wUpEpX8tvd0IddWXIxL7wh@fIDui3OKHaSO7N@DwPOVcnMO63IqQ9hswm5/F8pq5kBkP/ouu7KrPXPxr64xotW6T5jBqeQz1ECCYggcmnm57VPYOw9EgPCVMk6gpbDiF5QWes06PJ2KYjnxMMqZkKOuwKJkGCnZiSwZfEWE3QMebq7xgEG@Up4R3dRmoRy5IXlkYaUtp2m@FpNjV1UqYFe@5EEyedElSjmWl4QVe6wkLb5YtfkuQdxAjQbae1F6B2RVh5gfaxOl0EPT@xOA06KePony8pWRcxnzkVpVgjpUzm1GKc8Q5YkR75UzIKhKxNJpxRai6bnTsNdTq3jL2OcJDvyBY/76t2lICOE5ixZ4g67rVFWE6sUHEODE/V2PKfILQ6/gXhN77xx2DF00z25aO8c/LTae/sSfa09@X0N4cx0SLZrLI5ldGX2UZi6blCK2PeTfw0VmmhCTV42ksWOO0p8WGxSECI5LMnP@XPvuQJodMMktefZoQgiSEDJvn728sDfH4KzUwSi3wmNec8cczgZ18WHUVrK39iDOWBI5@EhdlU8jE97XOGLQLFfrq/XonLSZhfXSo8Wyo@o53QRXCbGwZXWG9z4dV5cEuqRIjtLC09p78luCFBiK@3oV@ih7fUT0lrIr4noXZS0iJUT3NuJxWxFdXxhCeoPFGZw6XCxcWJyvi4fMSG31XEcqYsx4IS00GL@7JYP8N@F@34IeTapHeIcCSsDMRGhI9Qc4Bskq/cxaGOmS4L7OfkqS3EbmUgNLz5jLVa9Pq9nFbWHG@hBCUaXjOd1cJqYXKOTk3RxAyd18rUwiNV3Hj5/D/@bf/XzCizsZT/MKTPUebXzMpqRr7SF/r11Py6zmxk1lFs5WtmnKc9MH19/h//m@pv/IXg4M14nf5sLBtYK@PMRq7MVb5kNlboS3Fpidr9P//8z9SHedmxIRfrfN1VjFjJUGTL7zHv0ntVQy9lW7oQixV2zAIMsTCkvTn9gGHU7dJqgY/pMtqq4jrQka@MPYpe4tkwa8SmQnKSYewpSDOSCmU0kBOQxoSipSzbDWO2AeaN0VQ/P/ZWQtoB/KzNOaImI9ONxyFMhuZlW0QDmJUWaT8vXzYKL9ORecda2tiUlIwKia2dlrWrT0vEDu/6wajdSFpJmOnabfg3wbkHPvSC5hXtqXphp//LMH9NLNktLq3mWzjcz7Mdd37AkHKDsfcbKYI6GRBtDNno1FVDGoF@FyG8XM4WRAr9TnQnZfJJkpY9CBpyhpXMSUxFxMfPlethdMeLVeks/yUFHpkzdSJIK1faaY9q7h@sqfRiVFDK8Z7XATbv2DhWh8DIiTXsgGWTl@I@4HTQ9MerDC/YCYlrIeq6FPH8ZrPu63fZ1FzapEpzU3OXQWdQTrckvDtip@LGRNNf1Mw7oeTaOEHI5VjQAVY3GPm0RS@n@Qn243ELCJOi71qjUHExWVu6rN7VN8ucdeWepm@k6RsaUWgJcTsRz1jR2JRdTGRLGUeVw6COK7WZDVNroUnaPPT4AxiEMiy1FtwSdHfYA5KoFndHW5XZw@byXph45CYQnz05WpTM1alM7PzomhLiQQ3dCe160hgJCETBXYOFMv0@FA@Iskkz2u6lJJ7fxGsT30OD4T7sI5SoHbZOgo/KstS7Ru6b9oh9KRWRQMeVtW2wU7J6RKCjEFtRCto0Dl7SDliqtcabLS5ohmON00CbkFDptJxTnTRUlF62pbPXSqIIepAuFJeePlteeb76AlnO5nRvZ4NBJQ@7gMGlTzBYo87SJhvPy@X0QloeIQX1dJOAPgssLuBg1nXjOCbs843zqFwsaGCFNMO64TQaUl0fVzLIGOIw8LAi0B4lO0xnsy/XTtCxs9Om84X@EX@b@IDMcCYcrS@kt8bhXRyZKtWVgANlFswcFCf7FBFUHP3GLhv0WweINhHA1lXYnhraRQSI0eWwf3VxaXOHp0NbHdGEIYJzXGrsoF4HozjAmIUVdFF94FCzvC/KBt7JdA9glIslATqfAKdppuNW@trSFLNjgRYhRNaExyquEC3TUZudmTt7fVXd255ELGOnoWO4nm3ZSsodRzJDABnk6rW6e0TU1dEu2JVUyyQ3EVWZBVwB5YrsDu/DV7qBRNQWVYysZr1hlL2PLEXmxTi0aVyVxhF4zYBZLHyblMav1fQCBDGCUJ8mRULMje5zbJLFONmDjHkKXk6vWTaib9thyAHmdGNpR1uUciHOKjCXugMgzm0KaelIYQ0jyl@rnHhZRhvJHMUrGkcD2gw52qkGM0tymgm2ug0lADayjhtaoP@1vS1XbVfpz86HbReK8mblr@h3lOL5bnyLGt/imqrtmCGwo8WyzS1spn6FixIxS0EHjI0RhPBtSVbEII4aUK3taNrLpD5JzO2zmCvArr5Wws3pqJ4kCPTCZyBzevMeheJgdx1@tiaHV9OSJgqpoqeFHHHdP7EtmszFrUaQhJQPALE0CSIK1BJz@1zM8GKBzpq3r/cuhrFrO7N5OsGysqEitX0nT2RP8uydlLmPLZY0WyytYRzv4wvm23t54zxo9bUvWsQc3@CNR3@MN3IPZ47cfwvmqP5juOOp5o6na5A9wh1R2HD26OQ07P0ZHHM@5jW43mxftHE@1LJ@ohMF1wLAAg8YwoeUXhYL6Nsd4kRlZ79YnFyPYCS0tAzHgD/U@We688/WIHP563bwX7Xzub9z55d155fXsNbMGHmt2lnh1v8@PY5VwmzywczhhborxZw/2tMV3dOVNaymM4b5/3tPc/@Pevpc9/T5GiImyIWDhK@/n5tFE6kcbtVqsbmFl9JBu7LIYz@bKx3svZrlNG0eWp2r8LIMbV39YfxXNf6rkEb8DWnocBcR2YZGe3nZnoqzvGiWfMqh4GQlPZH@msjoVn/1ghXvR/QCJUKaD7aGeqNCCrkrL@PbJi/WH2PpGy0@D8VZZLtOlomLc2sDLTvCohNPcdF8dZLMpZVoXdnmGMhq6@hgd/F/CBm6/ifthUbIY2hvgk7HrCT2FuwoijqlO2N1B7AP9Z4jwSqanIzsSHt7R@wyd7dU48AWE@vi7E2CXLXh/o/2Ul3oG1ZWbhwZEW08Xd/sqmCaa7YX8oT6LoVmd1n3@A9x6QvNpS/W1IHeGNxFKl8f@GlejPdpS8vL960BUsvDByZgwaXy98yq/ws)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2wcb8)

The program `0k 1.@` prints `0` in FBBI, `1` in CCBI. Command `1` is supposed to be executed 0 times, but CCBI still executes it
if there is a space after `k`. `k` with negative repeat count is already used in the polyglot to separate cfunge.
`k` with negative repeat count behaves like `k` with zero repeat count in FBBI and CCBI, so this `k` is now used to split
3 interpreters apart (FBBI #11, cfunge #285, CCBI #364):

```
001-;@,,,"285";# k 1;@,,,"364";# _'1:,,@
```

Answer (score 2):

## 370. Befunge-98 ([rfunge](https://github.com/tjol/rfunge)), 16280 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."4F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370";# _"582",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<          @,,,"369";@,,,"364";k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"763",,,@;z"482",,,@              @,,,"368_"z;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk5mnjx58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@9w03N71FBr77OTRo@u@WfY1ybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrZwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//0YZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@x1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79nPs4EBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmOfgKpwvXSoPiDRjE6hX9NblQ1g@JYkuEvoRyXBAEXGAN0FOQM6IWiZ5XKvo7NL4B4uk2Z7XBUJVBJVzoV5GXYvzMtHBJYlWl@ZZ@G5XXJIkVENa4DRqeY0SCwh8D0xQQlF8FAUf2xFD5L2eBjJNdxzatM8HEtwUSTJLkLhFwaABBXGBOHD7JqTti@u3LsXCC4btRoQG0hTwDZ7yahGG0xYysCpIbJM0oifiTxxjifYNxJJqC9GvuKlAbEJKLVWZxeToQs9jt6vBIgEaBVspOQAsX47f2qeTnvXG9pGT4wkYq8DocnsTsSqAIM/7w2127AaX8IqaL1xxCoSL6Yn0DeIl3yxQUU/mmt4KP7W/KJEWjiBJfBpdSWKeFLfb0HQe/Ou5YsE3AWdnXOjDhT/1J/IChlR2pcJgk57o6dyINgdOBz2bPfkcc3vizxQ6Zh2ZcnDcrq6Rd6bGF0M0j45eHC0e/Tz7RUwLLNTue6hmLlSAYfa6Uwa2FMlJ2uVzSiMBeCH7dthY8LlOKLgBzPJmUVEpXkXBpdZgM7Do69dRwlIQogOygHc@Lsm0vA4IHQJHd0bXhuE2SCVgizDJEFcJh2wAGbowKJjuB6U59n0zRtsvOuFGvv@WDJrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8JoAFQZ0@HxEpLUihpo0LDQtXNGZQno9Rar5eGBKlIyTz8eGj/aMagfXn1SSKongTkKV0tycDzVtTUMFXxQH2B64uS8mLgqM8TWVdieBudwnBi7Zla@ADANR1ZIdJ1iiomjeEsu9drxv5St2QAuidIFyXK6PyUPdDCxopBw5xXVR5V42iFLAYrEKvlSNWGLo8bHXzeaOYK0eHre4iz14UKC0KwDgQyI0uBJ16EvrICynSF6v94h8/uVFwj4RIUAWkoGSexWTKy7ME1F4kk8U9ZQ80NMcy5M@J44lMTCpKPFgXkLseKZ@R@Pszc5LIJPlTTUJcyH1390B7GET2p6xpJoOUBtTFcWRy@7i@1/WARmzHcgYO24I0XDoMMgSxaW01dweOfaOFdPTEqsZwiRD4L07c6GMYa8w3pDhSqqi6yhcbdds7By6tFrKIJMIQgVIovvxKP9MBXYt6Hx98Yx8GETWfyYTuDF2AgkgaQhe6uhFf8mASZCT75VlZwXC58EZvDwKkyHodVtpndGHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv7KIn3i3MD4K2d@jbTAh5MWOCIoO/j02ZODT/ef7n7RnGj5/NJ7LlMuAOIgvw7IQvKQ4w176xbvmlgtBBeDvuFi9wIuMAUFJVgtmnouMG4Zo8i8AGuohi@0Jj5xhnbcS16vzDmGSq/sLiehp9j5eFQ/ISjaPQuVEZevVuN4jvQznEzGXkVRoJcPpx0ZlFblVdex9IFC6WBgsCxFRdXl4BDnNbxVKaAw3tzgKfjkFogOc5pB1K2RA8oLrXkja2AJDp5mrSxzMARdGBfGDTcphxRMtVF6oCGArqyEdSMGTG@AW/8ZtJPISfurqlbidK1mtJwiBtGWuj/E3egboDolYLQCVCSvvbLmveY9NgcujZCuA4kxeYsmOTyGY4HFQJCkWVPU8wPkELfA@VLkFYSj11OczQUupeQzuaJayCugloGaBjKrhHNu0kifdIfSxJEAnuT0ad4gQoV9r6vbfXnLdwSFBbnvI6hqtvGi2bRbIKA371HZcN25MW811Fayym4m2fLjJ6tAvUvVQ9oNPIB2yQmkSU@2hp/19JvsrKdT7@oxZTIa@2OONGZPd0GQeuMAv@4Z0b6HCZRooLK1FFfByG@VFRNCFiYV8IaYUqBDwUgLpKdguSQQelE8BMoBvhVJwBazGbwefH9HhI@g0o10bzpxj9ZIUK7B2VJvDEikyeYucmkP5wcnMDqGlI9cGhoXmTQ7N@I4j657fLYSEvlr/EF60NVCCDQrH85I2@GuBiACSkXqOXAOoCucNh0uZhlR6QdKgwypTDj5ABKETasHA@AzkJhXZJdXhOdEPstVOrWdcxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17rNXrRuED2r8TgAjSoX4eu0KN4xunyWlSemWoASqLORMXJwKgGkK2IFBlVB5wvqqAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfY/T3gYl2DzxdJI1SigKT2WXziKrvSNxRdegPUfItshZWPNLHf6CcBApa3N9AsiT8DStKJM6JIn9N8CwY@CMRdAVcMocZAYaJec8aGfV3n4xphIlmlbQjxOF8EuohvbGzEK/F6PA2uHXBto2sHXSlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/VvyqEUCeJVtIAzOUHN6Y44TeqFSyrbTeUP2nhs8kNAVgHmJL@AA48WSths5kUqyf45oNyO@Ruu8h7Rx3XXPso@ATEAj4u4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jirrp7RgZ1VxQGg0UMRNuvNnINFvNi2Yv1byKpzF1sqrXQD8E5jVJjOSB60zHILg1chUJeFuyka20qp1aPBPfSiRKkgUZ6cnkR6VkSue4TsQNoKlEsxkHlPrYaXSHLsGbpbVkMkQUlKNvgpZhWYm4fFGC/DvJVjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7zQgqNHlcYZAU5Ej8wZoBI6Jgxx0TUFYpC0OIXd9RvGeDh3oxHCWTeQsnEGfbFXBbf0IBePcsk3PH1UoFvS9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs85dxd4SZvK0s6oYNw9k/ojZ6Irn8mgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNpPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3ZDgFZhlsT0sDVZljwegOHRbfvA/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDryvBDJopSCS6WgHRBG4pM4Iu0FYtmZVQqBGc9wdx8vjB@LYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMClEAKgXZP0Z48oR6sSx/QzNeNdQk/lIY0VLxNAzjiI8vRCbecXUfWg8ajSHrQzyHJkdETLOAffWCPMm8L1@gpWwKt0jruEEYIqA1yYi1srZEfoDjeuCdPZpBUSOCAGw3k2h0Ineesp2laoZvvV4IwpApA9hAaCbVSG1TcIEhSITDpN/I@nxYKdPRPDx/u87kTGmxxeMV5tPbI6U1BrvT1piPDHqTZPtCTaTsjE9AQpH9zah05zoRr@fCybmaGK83maGrpNOdzfVrm1nRdp@NYNBV0W9JF/Knr6ZbOJ6GC0N3PnoKs//zkuCZXIpEU/Wx0a944D7k6W47Pg@iaI623BstDHidMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDYK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjguSnuhauR/Nun3l7yz5H0qIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xGiR8jwSbgxdihMFVKA44f7QtfGKFI/vbpHDlcWn4SaEoWEFS4tHILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHejfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVygYpqJq0sH@jquE2DY8m2wVKUhU8BdSJmZaRmrPifusyrniEhj4Tm83ZRxntC9BLcLfk5j1lYFRpj9MafFWDkLgvw3bmTAKJD2PxievuEPgMS82WUQntM7X7jtWT@CoZEAzj@hU2kL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2fN@Bea9L6zQiR3aIhIOg@F@zyNH12yRow5J3J3tgyJy12JU@c9tDfKWVf31fKZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdo48/a2RaHIIw0nHlq8RbcRZsTwbBGQQl3EcOLtypMzEnJAnQTgQT66vKUKgZLZJA8QEGz6DKwoz8GmHRL43LRV36BmiqCQNL7s1HaWYkr@S@pU8mhs1pji8/rkc3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8OgiFV2fPJw/@hIBsr1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNZVOsBktPIV9lEvzj7CNElU2wXoaqB9tP30QNRVIHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6CcL9Vd0I4CoEljCTUiYBVVpb/uc1VLb@cFaD4FGES0J24VwHcmkl5apuvZQ8GGpJbIUqcK6swXtQ2E8TFNtWkv6FuhEvHoGGR0Ag1aDSY9Aa4HEQWWatV5XsAIC4qYO4AsSuK1BS0i72mBk1fA28QaQiCn7z2lr1oZKRyK7W5ChRtLvM3oPP6R@AihGXQnrEy280E9fcbHZmXga8Fcs79nNTpa6cvKmyTO0Q@50zRgw1TxHRof9XyPqnlXVjQyZCV0FQMViRgCTH/eIBPsxROnB90HkxGHokkuwiRriHK2eUl4ZBtaoxwCC6V8ca4CrRPYExPHKjNE/9oQFQ6oN7qbyTBPtsUxEDNWl6pxRAuwitn16RT6UyMpuPSoWmfOrTeE7raGVnNo0QYph6dWjdT4iZUui1FDcvA42rrSueNOn26rYhAyx7@gjp50IS6LwuDEKkrR/SgufUVOS9vIlnK1t@eSiMtuJn0@o6YUrlEkfudjrkuKiAB94UFzxXRgEkhPWtyTlaDswY4FQPjETAurr0sqn59/xFbwru/j9Z//udv9gD/N1tnCAMFzjyGjjYM3dhSUn9tY/lJ8YVuqxuWT5BPLVMnxJDrLpBd3YUq6VboWA2aFuElCYb/ES4p@C0OtIk3kBpvITNecr4iGDxXZ7JqUc0GltldF/fafiyeFS3/gGLXIyRwIcg0KBGxLt4IxowvwURUbGRjdxcq2DTFiJh5uw@nkym/g@B6ZyOaY/zd1jf9mJm83lENhe9cv6XJXf102nOk8ekglFMLK@Iuak9rwBKIA/5ycBudq6vPK8h3ggfPddEWQ5tyTo@7qMKzp95Y6pAW3uNv1BFGt@TgWvy@LorpH94LHeuxZlp0e09K9KEDofi7IRTcaypFkGZeQ7Old@Yogww/nMrCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0qrC/w/WOVoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatRI4DUndq6e7CdQuJL8oRLCOsm5H2h41nZtcBcWDM1KKsasHQERkwiGUGW@MWGeF2YrpFtj@Yq9AYHCeRQtdqFuB0J7hldA1NvQdD41s1cUNshEhkZx2mus45/taKD0NQTfl99Yj2ZmWp3oM5SVbX0mEcXzscLE0O4uTjHYR6bnoG3VYj9nRlQSdda6X/chcIpv2i03h3kbVnWo7Hjul@G4IGLmCB31cTdBSXpm5LNBkedd/Cg4I9DosG1a2BYxVKA0WH29pWn7p95Pv@8305XMihVPUODhWIP46t@s@1fP1UcU/vaiA6sOji/taI85YhdhWb8tde1tcOFANcuFtds0eZEqWUFT7VtyZjXHI51@fB82cYOtahNhg6xnMSp0G6wwTlEjgmLhexf5bccrfn1ns/pnQDbPGuSkQa99QyYLCi@40mZVpG/cAUaibz/iyqb02NqbFS0TjsvDLwWP0tSsb7FyrjV2PTn6nHxQE8mhLGeuNrhu9Vahyn8e1WZqJbZte4W5RZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdNxMMbCn46VWXdLO7KPbUTYcB13a6S2VDkM@lA@V7pCUluRzz6DfrRoT1/Bwg1gtn8lkfAEmsuKy9HKbJpUN074y@X0pY/JZ5LyIi6tsbsS5Og9CS3QL4loWpK1T7ClyuazYpm1M5nh/T27acRzrQ1oKmCoeGHZAW5Voq@1tLXZD3PEPkbDF1IWHEx6d/rpJCz7a@Lol4AeV5tsaPbok9F6tKeGi5wgXpJZfb5@@iSww3ZULHm7FOSG@@dZaL0v6syGqXJKLt/Y6LqE6HcPS@WNWyN0Gryxnb4W3zDT8xVpc3OVLuoul@Ng1pjSeA7LMHmgpQ2Nk0OstUr7eQxMZ/mNtpJmDv3XBM8PoKrN9o7suwtgEvmDjfWkNOSIsTRwb9KsJ7vNDPcXCnaS@7zoOHKz6rUTywUgfGNxmy22ccjFhgbtpuFq3cK6euqjwHTRdSLYwxrGeJKBTnRpzL3iuBPh03oV2nY7unm671vm7OAf6Hr193RbWm0OsPXSG9tAY8n3j4du6zgH0OOE2dm4rOpR6MMStbOPx0hb3KD4tx7LeB5/IGjmjdJz@yjLt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PmAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjXPKNgZOpzs07yq0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a6IGZNJD9FbtkxArzuXkV5q0fBjfBysa3R/9ogPa6HjFnll1QwdHcuWxvpp1@OzoehiFZwQjvRGfni7QsffK6@n5mQBNLKXKZze5csS6FhXdn/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tiLZWSkI4CuWRkQOBR12W7vM8t0sWyWX5bV6BoLalEkX0pH4Juf@8PzQ6akXlb8F@ir6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491aNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBTTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohx818tTLtN0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr5wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a66gCiLZVduL7oT99anumV@fQs3WERtabODLkG70aD@@rYD3VB@Y3cdLDREW0kewv9OTP5bIH71utsX50PRwR1PouGViCkmOEzFSXRv0hhUxr8/bh8YqFh2IH4NcGXvV3LoznuNpsTm5bptWNyc0y@o/16mO6zaB3VqI8@loPPX8x@oy0J6p6Cz06JT8vXMTgEuvgbWyoW5NVs9UR6ZcQQrzB8WFc500/g3TcgbsG6UMA6ENhDAUzlcQzgMYnp/hhhzXXkGJlPd7LnviRIfk8oq9hrY1skwybXNy@2zOZIKbc4InVoaPHHhCQXmCd/n@h0KQTlZj5Mndsv7iaPId4ztQ3rEzdbsGOkN7I1G1wM/V2At2H@OJDgftpZxHtbSuY0H3Aoe1sst0HXs6kdypfeuoULh1VKigtakIGbDE1/efPk9GqYF2a98lhQb2yBautRsGrhGZaYMgtp6PLscOdImH3E7SEW0VviPNLhpz6hK7fuis0neezWEAeW@FCZj/dPTQ6OKy4Z15f@o8dWwHRqMxMMrRkcHP/C9t9FidEJM9wVPtgJ/endkcE9g1gxCXNvSx0YH2tRau9xmLOOCH@kRfMxTR3CDpf6HrTloxrY7hvqJJv4h7nUq7XKDHxox0i/UEw/ugNOl2uUiM83FLfWRpxcYbO47N78RtM/BQn97OVWAooNv7L5TLuBF/aV5gpX62XNXDM75LxOhxoxTr6uoaHcfi91v2JNkm3xOgu6bhKU/QxgH5FXJMAunLu5WHFG/lIQvVCCTZM92jRfrVqsYCpDr7gC1AQ93tOrgS5jtu2Z0TMUxwB5sO9/bzjQMdQPwMOJbenfrGQu8qljXqjOi2VmGItOaR0cFTQR2y5jHRZzcbk88M@aYMIju6QgMAAbvCTl1giWegjSTvHraW9KhlrJpjuhGnXrtcTpt1JNs0um90nDVzCF@LuemlcKiz8ik518xVR7oRzSIrOp10X9mTlreugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xum94OzKysWA@ZjgxcZF5ehVkrujrekCrrrF5PD5mra0i@rT/gJaHdPy4fSrtrJU8ED/@HDz5RYBBuF3KB6RFgXXev4EPhp67tP96HAp853qRvzg6h3HgKYB07wWrlIQk8eM9A19a6SkDr2VOLzz4MIvuuRj1SxySywixJFrHriSEZ9plEhuBmN2vk8ENfyi5a750YPcm3g4ArDdKT4PxXGM1/rlhAjfJG3OypKhyxs0LO3/65CrnnAWcAecuZSGOPnsrYe3bw5PBEHnvqyvFpd4inI27IcUuGFbRSJjIl9Up3I@udfDtaz/QmyoNjVdp7ciBjhDX45isaEjxwZW7psXbeM7DiquhrtSAMNSarBcTHJ0@fpBZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47Pk7jSZNPjlcGR1M/gt7Rd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfk@t2l1cB33XJHTOkgnBmijQIyPuV2WO4WrrjM2eifzsfEZDJ7Iwb33zL6wtpKf6mfmAHshK69FFHVUVpYLuWRkZzYo24YbPte156k5Rm7ZpYfCH2u3o6DkkFXc7Grp4bYV/@tSDMv4OxE@LJGauUmtUTvCiu79fQumquo6PB/rfWhXll/bWMsRVq0PW87ZeywlG77yIoVe0gSoSjLv3EdelEbAuhW84fS87wnOztptMLcBCL0LKzv8uWHPdVuitazbxIsKpMZNbbdG@YbxHgtS4Q6fMzRWvnKNL9xSzxJdcibvyPjEjSTZ23twcFeCIx@Xt8f6@NPn7JnuoRGS2yNGS2y8R4kXktErCeet0ALe2uXUngugtFvhDcar@3OFHetuz7Hns7sX4egMKg7tZFw4hIVvFMmwzJm5aqzq8nmtZ6u3Gd2VNz/E4cyX5OCocRof0Ltv/zNVzWTI9BA@1Qx/vaNlgg7OEujS52jPLhp0chCyhi7KLTJ4JFdqo0@MGW5H4bPBq5T6leNb4Zaxr5hcP5zcFla6JSx3S343wtCTZeWMegvA/C1hLC@HwU8c63zoyHu6a3gr9h@vLNBtFSnfUpFyhDv71tJpYdF3rxfx8eiC/1hJrSfGxM2Nh07HzK2sw24fjUyyp2gs/Wa4v51Cd2l7y8Dxj3zw99X5nU@NlRk91d@sDiBOc7oyCJigMZzSkYibwcsLpB2QeQ17YHL7iuyBM9mnt1sUs/DE8@q9COb44XS8vsTAG/GTFNfZ@VLEz0Fnds499gCPxi3E9BW6P@6PW@2/TqZl4cQgmhl9fLIbUNfhsaJFclyU4otnS954eHRyeBzxc43ZbJ3SK83W6ZArQxa5fnqSW8p2u/7ibAWy1p83AnED@HH4XCsHcWb3yfFNloDq23AysoKQT3R7MWO61GA9Z0InDVcGPpvPaBvlypYe8l1sq8Lc7grvJcUeBmTThLw9pd1Gy/rt9jqqPDG@oLUHEIPYhIslHKhveMmY5YZBCSnJ2o7qnC6En6XiHo@Hpj1bGTRal4Z2kSZeeau7wS47tpxz9iS0KrSOPWirgetnhr2OOa06rCiVs7dLYdlrItW6duFfL/Ef65rkwTpB7RrPwA0Rt3ETTH/UVR4FL59pyTvjf3IcRL877p7l4Px9z5yO7o5MYFOpuyO669gfP9kLhBG1Cu@lfbs@/CQ8P3/syYHp/kTChjyTy99Jih6mRtvJiU20HbpJB6ch7uUl2/APK0OAGBx/9o9no4lB054aeL6afz1lUtuEbGo1NV9mO/hhogqoRknKEb3IkFuQV4NtXvgnjysV9Ypt1JhYEZl/9ju0y8xtCwNctIoKdWLSqco2JxCyGZxbZvSZDHbJaLoF9Ds1n4E3WYlacKj6J7uhSJsXzw6e7R@f7J48P25kWlf@ye@gErYNuQX2JT7K9kSou482EOO4pXGyOGBBdvQJD5ym8YJ6Mfws0HLVaktVW1RK3ME0mxe2rSh0@F2RrqB8kshzo1BkRuDFYQc1pvbx7R5U@Dl0Ok4PTcRBi5QntFmFZVZlPNZBJNm0/fDrX9GiUPzKWgW/s4YZ@8ahgRAHjtPzc/QMdvcV5Pho9@DJ86N9FhRwQTTnZm8yrJXz3HY4N8gB7dQ3aTdgjcX9JHFoq1ot/igOiInLcVYhcwVktxvoHKIF2EFDB37qLZbYJPiAwXjYKMp//qZyFZdxY3sS4saDQsUhWyB5IpSNjQ12AkTCHh4dfLZ/xLD8@w/JG1GEINgJnpX@sx/1@JcvAltGwRfm3BHJD2QLRojaSwiMCCzsHCDOqeuO139njr40QdYEwk9chN/oEQT6AgrQ7TmZIbxmoi5JVqP4d/F8C4JBRkRCgbV8XENBa4Cux85Mz0RbBliGPhrnWyZ23HZFBilltosf0cNP9en0GRYo@tSecANYvhmcGFCaHLKcNNukwvKPtoiRiPHtDSD2jgGiJfNsEwSVSYW9AkrEdYoKt3UhSfX4jSQB6Aq5JBRHIhFvWPPzlKarvPvVf6IMqgzcE3B/x3fPMg/g7Zf9tz64f4W7XyhIaDet/y3KEi0QWuz0a8ALEuIfcR/5dqDN7YssEIdGCgO@yswRNNMZYR2j8xz4XQJ2vICTaHwGjQbkBi3m2xXh@RluK4EmQyuKgiSF6o5MpzqMGd9iec10aCFfyKkKFFI6CwCSrf8Bnh3nAJPJCnQT4cwc116CCL29vc1EnPMwaoUqb1ll036RFV@GBd2EuML5EAvXYJAGkixSQFjdTwaDT0pNYlLkXnE1joyr58CoROE4euG77SNCZAlAFseRgcbjZ/iZyQlIAr4J3A5@mDHyHZhNH5CkwphErqQo@BY5PnUmQD7QSRdfeuIWOXCLMR8B0bakxz@@SpZnkR7lmz1rcZA8@OCM39dk5AEcVDZzfTCNtq34OYI4RhAVcRX5Nl6w5qRptxROmwzI9IcriNkG9y8pgzU0y@u9e9PuaOK61VBEFrt/bDs4ufMIKsMSmqJlFbWQXFQpl1tZJb9GfjZQHTRudAnZAZsCltE1zFfO2Nvd2z/45PDZ8Q3bmhQzfj0a8P36dqopyelGK3TEo9VabpIHj5Tjpw8eBQ2xKHQhwo2B8fs1UW@ryWLOFkEuzgBdr9qqEl6v3foSf86tBFwvb1a7rWiU6EY51MwH5Ev78KVHdJrueuZaaRW28vnbirSAp0RA7/Gj0DeKmkheXDVa2/WmHYvfpIQVHeFFTN7CTgCupre1qSCx36wcViz8LPIJfnDOi/bF7Oq@KG5m0XQbWmKYOKcL43a@RyQgUt8gG2CRgqwEUdf2vkMuoy9MMGr8s83c5lvUolWkwIXMbRiPgDoJvgCNXGRhQNa3nTrUvaFldoTAkhi3oRqYegzNp3IrYImk4H@GhGec8L8JPavMZNp0l0gityNYaXabOdYAXlKADo3S3bMp6L3PnDE3S0@bKx4agevIAfb7cMonYwz2yXQE8fr0ODJooQs4twSJAZPxsKhclgIu4VtjnaXQ3i3k10CbrH7F5VEvn5gl5aEx65kD4O2JZBo42keq2mKhxVasNFloteMitdmiFW7tih/jAfco2j/IbO9sUQC9ocum3TNmifh5PFlpQf7oHz///CyeFFfREpkP9u3p9q7bEQ6LX1Rv5yT6xO@dgZHeVdyiXL7JJcDvOmBuzy74Jla5LA89gb5xWEPJ/XjiPgEniBGJ/kgfs8TU5rYAZUaviWbCTpORNKnO7YzaLJUihQoeFCAzStknFx@/E7o9Zwmlhp/BBF/P7uHjjTlmDVWWW@CmTJJsE79VtwcSF1rHTAqgA0OSCoGtIQmBmgEl4p1E5gQOaTAc4sKDLCquCKZPd9F6gIM4oVqz@j0W@fbgsuQolssVv0GXuWKZAfXdZIeyAmBv8LlArgfs@maCAGeg/spCbMHIb3K8GOUb4wV57NsXguLEIraBA7NDDGAtLPd2hy7@Evs29BWQDyqV5yeP2qWkIrLQTtHANXu4XsXN24cqnv9BIuimylLUeJVrdB9jMrQI2eaGkNAw4SPqMOI1lhqLouH6l@4XtKmqt1K9n9BvBYiZwwHAP8/ZDsChFc9gImtF2Gpm/9OfxlDYSGyq6mnbPUvF85kq3NRqnuXZR5tNSdpsZGr3N3XQoiavZ03QyZWt3MMzY9jvHQyUpiiyLMspytbFxUX80dYz80WeFaSeqRVez@ZX2UL29ewqq5Zen47VQkN@PWuJpVr6tMWePfvibfttUpydzV@LzYQW2zu8FNUcqvyxSpld7BSysdMyqJ@QL2On7A1cp32G/@R@04u4dXR3@qDCxkUWazYB46pYFBWlEW/BP6n7L@Hiin@jLtflndbbt8mGrk9mc2aa5tjr9eDnDEGC1JLHDPTle8DpeQKFNelJGhReo1n/5nxCnrHZrjEYTPf1uoZHfeX77ercnD6aPP3G58H1HK83R5Fkb/yP46ZSCUlqrJinqLT1fAw/s/tnP964Sl88a2//2bdGirGBj0N8fOfqKbqP1fxHGxsfPXiQy6U1TePuZ9949vO7u7u5h@n8s0Z@JydlNrb/9E82NjRtW1M2Wp6ntuKN09MvRC2TE@U/@514@9mzr3tePft/fvNtXcVbEW5nrAh8Aq4sU8GJ9xL8VJSx3veKvYkBlauxOf21Y4H/xQZT6zvF//K9w9exSayuKZ@78JzEXscKpRh3ggPessHbWawe28ZohavYXKnVauAs/pd/C@nrnwAcDJlvw62eD2AV5rG6VKMkl7F6ARyqpkG@//c3vxkpIWcTNRLjgus@a8Al5oqauNOCa4uubQHtP0oZRQni2ZPhxHCYWrqn3sMXE17gYRtoSN@YNGP4oXF2eJ@xo0YqlWrJbQku@QVNEimqqjVV9R6wA@mjrVpN2mLcwmU2m7@HVrqTNKU1cGDENO59/g9xxVZ5Vn9mcEdCrLBx/@XDeh3qlK1nt@opuvyORH2qWBId577I0uxlHFSQRuvlE8bN8tbFTEkT0@n0/Ta9zxBX0iykJLz4PRYLfbDLsut@S0kgiu8b@/B4sX28/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PsPaCDT7pl9ZQsinUGXqMN1v1Lp1uti3RUvmvheBzrKVEqVktK@aia2gAO1jpia@fgyns/Gj/lHwFXGmklKDRdlW/ezx/d6bOFd5z71qJ8fwCOTB/NrQY4lrJE7xNqNeDC0@luJpcZZvSWhQFSTGmoh35J4qnpwlVnjPjSTqBXLYquu5bVDdr894xcbbnrMiYFmWAjw6Je3vqhbPQxZvNWjXrF6kKy@iPOh8cLyCrFGQ2kZNCAEfuz@RmWjVClUNKVdX38BaUZfKaphGM@82FksvDhmYwuExkLSvO4XNEX4wgIKZh8SDySj92G@1ErZgipWfZfWZmIViETLStqgLWZUMextOL8P1wb80T9c4SveN8jH96YoN68NVlG3tKyS/6iwr@H4escVLasA4wTrdjqdN90OSB263tG7ujrRp/pMn@uTzrQz60y60y7DLrM8o5918k7JmTFOgLIUy@bVzdg9Iuq3jQ12xLlQi6WCq5m683ouy23fSQ4Hf5LkzGJC7B/gqquayrZgfMrADYQycoLOjH@qKrAYCFoXrbdbjbdb0EHrqW1ijq265JcSHnL7fislXV01wF2t@v/b9dBZpYu7oHKtq1Rq@0UdpI8X9UYKQL7wQcoSI6Byu97appAwMz83P3i7BfKLlNpubNecPfrJ1EGkeM6JF5z7LQC8vVTY@/dTMrjuA4D6JvTHZCq1KUkbODY2/LECIrfqqaBWWIYESAsXFz/jDxQ96MVX21f1q8b21dX2Nvxv0/3Kf4Lv1faNf3osrjVxFuEtZC3NhlJvKk2fWbTgXVbq6CMrTXDU4QnxGlmt1GqgAy659d/mv5xe3EMfLHJLhlILsS22FUNzjdnYlhB7@e7L/wV/zXdf/j7Kiwz@jIoQu8BurWyhtlnmSifcmP3UZk/5ZYMbf8Er@qDH0zp62vxm44KUoryUWYXP@SfUUiEp4wDcdvpttAAhs5cQ9QbvY6JWKojtlDrXWGxbLBSJ3f3cjSsej/@jl1q5GOcTNWjC4KXneU8jpVyUEyJXtYwqqZd1bqWff1Dl51Zd/@jn1l1C7LLMjArgp@sxjhkhBoQUUxRJghGrvj3CTe64ViKhWnpW@0J6vivhPIo@oZWwLp8jqB3s18rlOl/m2XxG3Wbr4RbcVfjf34B6sGYf4jb7te4IJOBmP5vXmmjTPSZ1XuPfkzf4x066@Hf0Gv/YyRv8O5rgH3vawb@T1/i328G/kxH@PXiNf0/f4N/zAf41v5LNqlVx84JQk1LL6tXmTCQUVWM79eZXJu68Yhl2w@y1/M8VZXNllow1v2LM8KP1Fe7Zj//ku9/6VrxWi0tx@ghMTnVcpiargH2okRev3o8LsRrbVDfVjJXpZtSO2gGHyTIuywwzQ7UHikpbZRmDZeaZOcuMHLUHLgP@MuAyM32WGbCMnbEhIoSCa9LOTNDVh8cA/voAyIU/E/dsdtRMl0FGFgpt9P1IBA@uy3ZTaLA4E18aoGvKqpyRC2YLv7rTEF@@bCpbLa1cYjISldxuvGzGW2JTREvsWjnHOnNjo/lShKE5I3LiQx8W8zxQYKsxpdlUOJoAA4TFq6t2e//Th@22gsNQ86lzuPg/PBxFX2/9Hx06Tw@dkQP/h4eH0HWMeup@Chj0/fs1YNj@YydWr@40K8T2A9YfU7Z3mvWshO5CCri5hn6pD7wWEOFZ32gK8fME6h7nqH5UPz@vnlXJfR68gqNdXUQIonGH/4TrHIa4QB05h@vsHB30hs7zz5uhizuUz8/B63MGelf4Dwpe9PW/wr/539b/0@csyRKNVjJxcbWdoCuJf8nkxdXFlX@vJxMJ/yWxDX/oAe@Y5OKqjk6KdAGuRiLZSl5dcT@4J5LbHGAdstmuU9pFPBgWYmGWlC2/Jf7rPiFr/2rGqyD3ct06n6F@FBOrTF/sq2k2Z5lMstoJPjKBq8T6JW1eSFbpC4ObnYba@tPfoQ@J7CQpUj5XrapbjL9oOa1azQVvxVK1WgpeNhOJ8s2rntlRC6B/5HLJZLUKLzsB2Ay8QtoGe5tiNdaEe@vePZ5JSbu8DGBmc4VURs1g6iCnPGRreHrXZ7gXB4f0DQ5gNfkYfvyGs5JEhr7gg1@Ji4sV8d69hP/1@Z3d5L17WjlzeRn6jMfgpS55tds902230T97eSm2RdoHU87De6Z0ealmyik1nnTcxKf4eUHIKiGp7COtTrmWgY1ruSIE@wXIb28XcvV6IQc@hVI8iWvqDSx@C8obF@NVMXZBdVBLRc4BxSp6R/cHQV/GQYFdXMWoQVkun0wAI02CDHgVwz8XeS4fbvL5JGDmSuQx1XKZR02yXCFRSpX9v9oGaOUg5PA/lNSyqdxWces@yLz4581WXciTqxdGTb2qXRgVnFW/qnb9DzWjHQvj3r1sGVBUylSbQrv9cPdkt92uiaKIghLc0JO4u4DmPdx4g2qeL7c4RirV@9TMainPoD15HCkOIwQrAdIVbSuvlhBJgtlHMzWAEoFrSxtsQ9DoiTehzDG3AZ6gzkDmPbhYj3XYAC82QOWNmcyii1mMh9O92w0jOfzyQ8NXSkv6XeBjhJfg98IsJ1EYxJ892d3bP0lr2xKLaY9299La8fMHMRVf84t3Cs7i@9H@7sPD55Dg2ZP93eP9jw8@23/@DPw9dr64Aqbv3xfPqGvF@zn7XHjlvtENQzemhtE@n07PX7NXptk2oTGtKVTKGbjMM9pQl7G@qFcVfl3T01@90t0xXezdD7/97of/3bvf/u673/72u9/@/k@@/P634fcj@H2XP7/7b8p5vP/ky3/2u@9@67fB8z/A74/g9@OffPnr3@Q/ev9j@P2niN8f@79IPP4TANYv/@TL7/3OT778lR/A71/6vx/c/P3qj1f/vv8L63@Y7nu/e3uc7/5b@P0ehxXE/e5vcT983oj/Wzzer/zg3b/4d/z/T/0/dP72u3/xx3jzX/7pD/70P7371r/XtNKf/ut3v/C9d7/wrXe/8J13v/CPtXe//q/VTPT2u@@@/wd/9Ye/91d/@D/S/4/o/nvv8//uB//0L/7Xv/jf/@IP/d@P4ffvwPXjv/j30FX@9g9@iP/f@4O//aMf4v///K/@9g9@7W9/@X8ix29wx//zL/8Nv//1r/7Hv/nN7/zVj7/5N7/247/5jT/4q//jV/6vX/@Pf/3f//5f/5Nvoedv/Piv/uiX//Jb3/7LX/jnf/mtL9fcv33r/cv38P/yH8Dn/cv5PnDep14f6vPlz1Sevw82FrkAnQB1/9K7X/9FIPB/wdi7b/8IT4DBb83/jzSV4vyIv/1/wKHdrDOGZMAFv1979@3vIor@B0AR/If4@k74shTCX76zeAG0/uaKRL/0ky//@e/QW8yo1GnVBsfuklZKbYF@s1Uu@@O3v6ADSX5xGVoIwM/pO8ihlsK@g7zt3Q@/@e53/vG7H/7Gux/@Mg7eUq6c3k1L6h2rYRAx/x7xMGLhfeJhxC8w/xRNsUmpL@CNfeEHfvHFF0L7UsGjhvcvwfcL8uIX40F4FNEPCsLQH88msksWdfvOjO/c9H3DnBlrvHzZwvVW8MPcUyR7bAWiUT7LZim/YDPGl3XQHyLNtsg5wzv5YvBMwNvif@GcCSw186d74ZlaOMnhp/Oz4E4hD9mkZuFiEslqjEtHW9yH1okp31yZYQ1ms9QMlGBwQA4pCHoA4nitlsKENV4eeOVFq5cYFSWVqkG9MTVPk26XEMTsAUGBlLXUEWtv1WY8YQrh1QN0pAT0OhJVTUyVag8hw9rsIUNYCJzAvnxZq5dqszqCe8vxkZqlHlCZEFgtNau/hfcawYR0QuzhWyhKqZZK1UuYIVaSN0@6zRspT5WjuqdYym8DeOJ2/537jH0kqiWRLxJsIMJ4bLynFrExIkSH8GZqy68O/QdO@m0RwjcoKz8XxsN3SDbd4eIqRgC4kiTLMoMfrr/vsPsQPOOgUpQtPFIcQooogigg9GA4P5QSUtS@KXqB/GO1rQ@@EBhWZnNzU4jVxax4KBPqFIW5pxU6@4DbAVG9qDCxUBbR26CDIEFZIH2V8t@M48JanHHA7KMU/92/v8U@gmrSc@EnMCmVdXJOjEPZTqVEDeDXnZTwAtQSAeiUAF0K8qxGC3kpIZ1mTK7FMIwdHh76hSCPFzUhBWSuZVV8x@Wk6XQagxSynJbTaf8p05M8ZN8hU6j/lDcRufT9baZpuSpoT1WGXiyq6qigAqPn27dvoVVof1XlAJRP5m@10nIlCgQPbnHFsubBgSEtVxa4Zs7UQo6xBE2xwpVkSYEl2FZS4LvyeSGCKxHXSqU4xQPsy4mtYOddQSVywOnVWB0LGlxcJSzlk0Hg3iHbO3z6dP/Tk3GrxQSDvidutMeu0zU8L4Fhu58@5CcytHIhGWs0EPRJRUMGI@xXMsSMDx4eHRxXGK@03wQJKliV1lX9apZVITYef74d83ceifhJPEc8xntlUbeEVs5C0lhdiHUN1CxwwRwV4CqrCk@9wQNnBjp9WhTTagE1uyRNKjPh550pQ4Ot3LoL9Ck8pyFvbxMGhPqFREsX6ITWKgj1ur9nj6lC/Xj/BBKcHDJVy8hC/Qs2kzFD6UqoWzXLsAeT4SZufhObGTFSp81GJo1/WjYLdzVXSKv5Ymtjw7qQMM8mNdsF7mK8gtcLCavxVbiY8FWBfRW84II8cGsi8/eFHhxW/c15aBotwXfoiWoeullSwHlsDk4YR68qUPfyQpAQ2/jGNyasXgf9Wjp4JMSAWwxZsD9NMnvyUKZm7k1dg0IHjPXMz0z81qHcM72xpc@h6wA2YldXV32AdPCIaXWNXnmKHt6vuuTTAffVTBdidqVSe6vmioJ2Wqm8zWqaAB7CloIb4DaAAGgfwZbC/6oeZJLNlhTgVKoowiObzQo4dywIFUNgtFfkbaZWkzgNZnMqbRUR8PMZ@qymhZcfd/bRIm42w@NiCASwwcRlmSCsyMP8t4JAb4A03B1HH2uu@p0zc@9eFicxsrlMOFtBNWZX0Dab2VwWMS78/xcewOKrOdvjejajbitjcOrgzG0rOjg74MxvKx1wmuAsbysmOKf1rJrZVqZ1gQnb3DgqQ9srNXFizNAWM/cT655h9WU8W1QTKQNN3PaNjdeDhPVered06Uvr1Z5s4hfv8aQ0T5DLiVXHRrN9NTTgQWfLWSJ5IQxq53SeWzBqAxktwbi2bgk9ueP05rI3mVt4Ssdy3FocxMF4ELCAboAcgnNfO9lsrtJgLXnsjHcELV9MNdQMDCD4U0tpLb1h7BSLlZ7ctQzd3clX8qV0Dw8A@UtcO/lMZSB/8fTJ48lkfGTQqaCdXBkSoO00tHK0U6rk861GQxRTDcqmhd@J5uxJ2tiAPm3oPQmeuADmSVqpBYl7plurxeM7WVWT1Eo2U7oSFohDnGMN6wImTWHN0oj3C58DVGzHBmZTSetp84KwUOn3@1dbF6nFi6BfSPwN8HMl6enORfhalSLxKmyalsxFIPjofUD3hb@2VxG1fEmsNqqL92JBrLauhPsjo2fqeBiombm4maoATJlDjUFGTSZcVVzHmVQ6Rt9xjUXErFoIIvIC3YyQE6/C7JoZzPHiZnaFSKTZxU0oubx4FaYKiiVcXQHeObIB7b7l2zptmm2o5VxrH1gQkM92YBQXo8VevBBiW0efZet1aOqLXFHL5XN5LVso5IsajDflXCFfgs6WKWTymgZQcuVSuXgFdK0ob2P0zTu2dxHQe4Ws/if0Cjdb2Wix5NtPTeuilJV4ORLJ6tVV7K0Q@@joMw0GyLVXAgbdzzSpXsvmy@DKokvLQoGZoGmSlpWyqqRm8f8Oh4b/7x9fg38N75AqqwknaMvmUxg2Yai32RO0iTFx2ImDX0UasAdGd02MvaFOO5r3XMfz/h5xHuj2KQ96aHIDsmHQYx0/DeeNzMlwTYzn4xGawTHcfzAI@6MOFBDZIY/wAG6u5TirIhTZ82dravk0NNkOyOA22yH60cHHj08iz5P93b3HQoE9OPz04bVH3o@UZ0/2H52Er0UeGiTNhyB@fv/Jk@uv/iN3@PyoP3Vc/AmPDp/nFrfQCw/MCjm4liOF3gTEv@ErCZYgUYAili8GDlXAYxb3QDm@5zvzhYUzg87P@Wlg0wu3/fOD4RXhJDgirDPktB2Ddbm1I9TWyRKhL8urxbIgjJntnLNihvUcy9LxO/f9DfAc6njc0UCB1rKQEjHrc8e1eudmz9gQnuLJyrKK3xTHQgiPAcho2iUrFiDMoF3bHn6BHpelOtbUYNMxW@sJD/RCp2sOhjAGnztBBKGj6wx@H3pBeiN6TW73mPA8yO9GiHUzugA6XUkU90TxsT7R61XXqHqZSuXePfWZK5bFMQzJujcw9mdAtew59CLdnafFiSzmHrH2ABc2LGeMKog3boDMXtYarZ2cVi9l8tnSX//mj/7uT35tUFObmb2MtL3z9Em@ArwNxFhGkqovzcqk12jlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU0qITFMmgFGbWkFkr5spou5coghuTKEJovF31ZWAmEX2WrAmDtLn7keptUI3kIOhBfh2RvEnqSxfTwfcpEA9KIAmqhEzo7vmXWYARlaoZliwwg6qzLYo8e7WUePRLFB/iC@zj2MqLYw5d8KZMpPhBFg0L2SihSiQ5PU0JzgeKEv2QyDwDJUw4ALe2L4hBf9gs4nyaKJr7s7T56hPn08UXD9BDtlIfwFyt4KUI0G19ARCcAr0NoEG2X55Ojgu7jC2aJIY94yB6EieLHQXEw5IhH4wAeBzXd3RXFA/6yu4she1TtPC/o1/Blly5RdOEFaF8UB@AYuNDrRLEDTuwBotgFV3eugx9@UByNsdsTXRTnHD2IIFGcUWy9eyqK7cAfs/nML00esVuhF5XX@j69lPFPFLWg0BgtG75kRTEXvuSgbo8ff6YPJz1jwK@5y59dqOnjx1ndnE33H3U@/rgzGHTc@e7@x0cYtLf3GMSR@dTtDDp@wk4bLgdS7T3W9NPR/PoFtT5otyu6tTLoa@12TrevBbXnbQNLCKleQ8n8a4AZjdp7ELT3uH1fX7WOTADb2PlH8Ozg9WAEzwd6hwcFFwXRc9bpiFUkf0VpJgRUGHAFGLvjKTBTOz3Su65TxfdZjWXSKLPMG4VMq0oBbASCf6Z6heH9BN51nPxJXswbs1qmVZvVihrfiNRPiM2ZljfF9MZoRy3nKxv6jqrlUrMKmq9w@nEWl9QdllDvbb1hiU@TOxooAWJzZ0cSG2prR1NLlULxxdZUFJMVvO9ki5U3iUw8wxjeko1ia6eYj6QoFlO6olWKRRDFACcTGNE7OCfTTiTODf00mcTS0gwBVIHqyuZUT7PaT8zSsxovF5snq7OaWuVGiFnmBrAeWryfdieOy0EOANxsJ1PBJfiEqJZLIhRAURLJZMj0QGEXFntAP//6yenJyRck89X9yYtnroHcq@q/fvx4Tz44DN7QVr38CEVRx5X3kGsthXCZNPA6ASVEfgyjKCh0gR8eE3QdS96nrXMgzwYBgfUl2bcbK588XoJzPHTOec5oZaFKxgftrsHQlL/ZY3qtDi69xxJUKqYnz2n8btfrtXZtRIYIoIpBqq8xsnO/AHPg8bKHth8o@QUenfMD2rXMVbVTm8VmAKddY5L6cuT0XmqpbrWHFvwf1B5g4mobnp2qUTNc13FFUKfFan/Hrk1tT@8bzwwXrZocHG6CNIHn6RJ9ZiQ3WXMfY@@hqnIl1V1mL0r26XSU0KV6J7nshRNzoQciJ/H1oNIXdMQTN2lcVfs1lngBUV/Du7vJEj35QXInVwU8PWDtJHhlXvZf9pnGCrkqqRoJhAVdifCD9dZZslb/Gjw47NNKBUrjN/QpQMXMALDZowCIPTavqt2axRISm7EkISlXHdQamPwSb9uSKLYkqXHZEuqS9LlQh/5ancf0mjft0MdfWKajaplCdQZ@ajFXHULz6i9mVbc2noKEYMGrP5/HT7PqVUAq4A7AvLlMvPvFbya3pXyN@1UJ1KUFkkdbbtdmVRvNSQJh1LI1CEg1cpk0KPFwK6ZhzNcKabWQzqZzaamIvjDgp/Np8AQlBwSMhJUQGRPTmVlGVtOqoaYTmZdm72UyfZoAuYWQxpLpibNvT0cMfKCpkDbpFZ6AnpS2ZYHy1XOYvi0RsQLLqGLFAOtDNjbTQwR1ZOgWpUgmJZbdSlibCYyzeTId7zdalcr@bPx1CEpIr3cKqWIm9SaZrCY2kjXPeC3Uq0Id2QvVerwBlOtPdTJvOmpAK4NLLWqVRqODVSxm0tlMFmpnti8H22JdbKUzGwUVmuiKEdtgnG9EZ/9Q4ln4jdsofFsGNJ1a1qqCTFNx2ZImlZX8Vj7DpwN5SmHsszfEJEs0xeDkdiIeL2rxeDJexYWIDdGfeQaeRvwsDtw1fk/dEUEYEytiWcMIC9ZIh3MzQelAHLsSUCpkOdBtL4Sri6vtuvAV4RiPXG5rL/Cv@OLp7iH@fQW8yvBaevH0@eHzw0cCU2ivp9yOVTeqcrVdhRdJrt8XYhXGgJM2fbNSygZjH7qLNLVdf8GfTTw@AHAFMhHdYC3a3WWYqLixz9BkwQ6LQx10d9TQtGyroRVh7ANuGkTVNLWKyzQxPKAg16ExvAso33aqjqf9vsbmcz0lBdr@PcYGqU2B0BO7PhWwW9sdHO0GG9R291ZPGGzOFJyjXh1YB3no9FT1j@0UM2I1xtpi3j8e1xREETfBxS7isfgV/MXiQcIXb4KjPgWxepopb984DFQODwPlIAaatdwWYvfpuKPGjzuyWHjgEVdz/YWYbK7AkuVgneQr8fuxeDyOCxIV5r2NxVbV4bQqFgtZKnL1jZjzS7/yiFKpLb6pvqASE9UFZ9G@9lIDgo/ZTuABKh9Ox8GAnM/jAkBMeTn2vqGVsk8PDu2H7qPIuagX9Rh@2VvCI17Vyov2xqkKhJ4Vs6fpGLsfo2MBYhlKpXEPwPEpU6EUgOu4WoGiCrHmxuWGg0s7LNxw@Nb@5OuMjePZHGC9WYvNajl/J7tar0vqtoaW5oqsAuNXXy1Imcs676F1CihoEPLuF3@Qm22X4F3LqPCuafmUVq@rWxpLxsbvvvx9NBp0sf/Z7hMWxwWBv/uT39GKf/cn/4r2zMWvaJFAyxZjEBOdaqEYu7gYX1xcwcXD8rFWjBcqV0yCmy9YqbG6ompZ27arrKLo@lYxldPu21XFj6sW1WTMk2L@NtFsIS8lEqoCpdrKljJJCLv0Y2qZErwFS2U8uliAFoEK7B@ZeU29v70D9dvJ5rTqBtCWGh6lZeHftuGVUWV9@vKSMXjp1nuDgamRS1FY5a3Ett9K2@wtLlS9lTbYy1odNzyoeAA3WMjZwgOJuJgZr6eUrTgDfY/VG1fVq1aKVoJAMX5hGFt28xp5NjfwRMqy15YNf8aWR3@YKPDw4DV4M7ZeeWJiK6kovZ54k@y3DZavA8FsKYtjwmwrWN/hf5LUTL77xV/XtMLf/cmvXrYv219ooDOXywVVi/30p9tTe@oZvfpPAcAtBmMCvZdEX7Tsgo5QX2bcYqbppwodchdU9amNugGPH2jPqC8zkKvMgW30SHsWzlAWpMZtc5uFvQRF20J7EmnSLchGWLIqCIEQznUHd9BNEwy2hWZeG62kcCF8FYNA1GCgf1SFry5AgccIhAun2/asqTumEz0JSqe20uweJIEcvormIDfIDoY/TknAsJWtm0l5kT3CGsmNbGR4HhqXhCFW@Cok8W1hW3M21tFkC8Y0bRgYZYxC5aSAXgPybkHeFk/QJt8E1Z5HSDNeOp7IBv1C@CqISoQFEyQoZm5DhCowqq8CAqAOCR@w2WLbLJtkF2YqVV1YrrzCswdoW1MPzEUImAyh9dA8SZC4ivHAC/Qa/Poq0oXfwiDARjwDIBwG36pQA80Ik9MbCqVkz@W9QQEssp2WoKqxe/cWparVzF6SUY0Q/qk5xok9agd7dVkBWKBVftSriGmGNkGrgW9IdoDxFBUXqE7ixkCrkaRMxNcrQYD/9yZapMhrTUUBVayA3168V3QBZZAY0c7bsMu2a0zVikkWFr4LZe9SoejQfqgqN2cfydoXQeAVlPCnseDbRsC0TqKTpT7dXrcXwkCRmOKHZdBqHGcGvp0PbhcOmd/BJEgdpoKqmBbF7psuKHG0hyIwSZnIqklMtjDhSeUgPq7lGG7SzyfxQakwNoOnjqYV/Xw2yCRU14EG9caOTbYYyVYUnpAAigAe5Zux48We2uf4ITK/bShxtEQembBDyscSk21J@oI7pcVNDB0XlP0AN2lmDGTWHfWYVmYJIjQyt2eH4JKUiArcAV0AcdyxjBEU6dgw6FidV1GUAciH0w7ZHHxqAl0NH5kwAtme8pAjWDk3T03lBC0CS04fT99xCy4xFCmx@/H9Er59P8txTpllnhp8DjyxZP/GY6ANgUCfBswufoDYCm7E0bJpnJRR0zwW/IrwKHJnKR1Ju5GYJ28@s@pGoo0teknjjQmtYhlnuh3BL12Xgj8N4M29wIIW2YGCdzlkuYZvO6cWR6sYoVEowbcFViMzVDKurYwTYkwMbGihUxi7xhlDhV7AMQaYZjewRoO9GGr7VRoAqO9Bz0LTmhO3gjaUoCRuL9GFruczeJt9xLKagBG5gTPfGBnAwKavLUOHMEiK9fAmPWgYmRYUkK9A7xz1IAytd/jkh@kD6kY3mT1dkDfb8MHhoEN51RjvFsFLPvKCvQPpmaq@AYEFKOGKkmwkxBSATYlJkYMO019PzqldIF5SYTchpRlC8FENUEhU0JHloO3EyBfDBAh4oHv8sxK@4c3z83OZrMFOXVM2PPyKlufYuqWMBybI2I4yMUZj/3vFJn6n3oe7cEn843nyeDjemaF0Wyvfm/OnIPS9mr@dKRHve3EcHM/wI1GDEVmOQ5NtHhHUI5M@MNdN@LurOP1prfRFQH8VpD@pFL9CIIwhmFl6nu6mAVi60z1N9897VT/gjDokAIdWNAJPtNHsBi8jL3CZ434Yw5kgHw2DOtYprVADJJHPXi@y5jUMYs6DV/99bM4gkW2cs13X1ecJCk9ibCTgxJzEHjaHYZ9CwIkmty@4wWBz1pi3lpLPwuQwqIX7M1w0Cydc3A6UW4/G8BkPn0H4jIfPFpkG2TZmLS6SodcVVgepHq2JBjERzDyIc8UtLS9CCDLI46A7kR/GnC/5XcGvW6PUAb75G7RjLSAMoIkxINxIKI0XzUazZXvG@VYrpQyA2EVCBLQ4gG60CKfnvdCN2LfOrLHjLXnZaEQWRiW/3OjVHfrUwGkF6xg2EBEGx5eJdj8HI38jCRcI/AoDBJTDIBBFg91JwkxWQ2vlFAiE0xAXOOYFa/iFaZH05Qf5fiAucdRzxEYBtSKA0D@sEhQTQljQc/g3EwPu8LnrQJwgrkSfeRuh/bl4Kw6YvNZVOK@pUiNFSiVJQTEB7Siu1q5XJQiHpmhcC4pU88pv/2jxNz64@H3oF6tLTwTLB4yqEO0quHcTRAi/uxBWWb0WaVcogbKlW4YLI9c@l0/90Rqy2VICNYPng1Xwzs1Jd5iINH43yduHToiKtlgJSWFeq0EV5zXeLXm/CFDKER4m8/xk84AQ/PScgQCMzMpkhp9sFk02q9U442CzNcnOI4WcUSFnPAmPPVtTyJafDLSng2B4weZpgXSKm0tFgKfyYRTEoLHIPP3MwOX@V2gbE1dM/DwXPIeowKchFLGRzrqtlbk3IoWOMK1rAJAQbwDo8c8vV4TrDE@VwreQR3FUBjyKv/lkwHkFEBix4Cq3H50IiYx0YBD4xRSNA9B3xVRDEFWa9ca/DP@J6cAz@Kk3PTPLMdVlz0z62t8/iGcLMRvpoBHpQ83kkCGjJvPc9g2vRmWOGNudgoIDUl3n3GGJFcI2@CtTP6nSsZyOMtJx2w5@lJX7yuN5MtAfcN2I3R87E33i5HIVrjSZRHar8uc6gzmwHfyWU8SGPMh6Pcfw7PgEGrXrDGzTM9IMzXueGr7aYfgftRCicrLvdDxB8DeQcTUWQXO6QlG33cbPxLfbCdyXmayEm8xpmyaSZzwuoP4Lrkh6YE8@0MNxwum8MrqT5N0w8YMIfrITs3uaOBz7gTgnu8uAh3VB/ofQIUgwzHMWmiMZW0dRujNJ0Ic8hs7IGYDUN/VkAVNfA3@wgI0F0sdjKkua6ajSViKfxaBekuim9aSf9GsfnJR9TUvoyTC9tgxgCRlp5l7HMWLWXZFde212PFmQ3/GHl/c4Wt7j28tLWvj1MnPVvMYDPyzrbGIBASIuipG9uxhYdeBbvRvFWSpK6I1yFU/w3kXs0ba4HpZ0F6Lu@tHlPtBHOnzz4C0s@Gfr8H97AwbJ99@3@XTo9ux4DvxmhDtME/T5PS9Y/k1A9IMk8p6b2YWk/fA984K4@OXTRyhCgBhLjMtGO9HQMcegdnvhBHIA@A6ax51oN@ietqfVeOCKMrlnaXaqrW@ih@2eYelzo5fwY6YjcIMaH4HCRvzq/SqOjI6YnsN1vQSMXckwFIZxRDqPVFlDMnr6LJlcT1Y8ihlSD82UUwkP1uMPw2@wZpziq/HZatAD4vEYTseemTj9OZ6P5/xTBBb/9prPR/n4w1sSrVzcjRDAAx891fQi2@Rt7PMoEVbpPUaEMK68XGW0FB5ARONRN9vww1B0d02hcSOJakErC8sf4Vnd4uZtLR6hioAm@WLU@5HkXUT33jQXITUObMHC9j5sCLkBGfesdLuJKETuc2uLOfYNnoB@NE9nrxlV2isYapiSON3EJHWb5IukgJrxATxxwukzeCLAgTFpc4IK6oZzWv7nTBmFjPRxRGrxfUBIBygRLP6/3X3tWhvJkuZv6irSEm5UplSSsMFYWNgChK1zMHj4sNuLaXUhlUBtIalV4kNtu5@Z@bE3sPN/LmFvZe5hfu1VnI03IrMqSxIYd5/dM8@c57QpVWVGRkZGRkZmxoeQXKNhlXLMMxX//DVus3lrm82pNpupNuMZkG7SKuQ0U03qUcDw3DUE3bA9ukU64xP2zvTnLrFN/@v1gyFOKz4vdBbKHU8tXC2USSAvhAvlWo6E8kJrobzFD9FC@YAfPi2U/0oPydxa@LJQNtMCBYb0kx9e4r0W4fjdXChv5tyvzij4FEamXX@hHI8plXkhP5kiRAr0m7RGXLH1@rqbo2FICxsrlZ4Cx0Qetk98DuPxf0X6v6TV4oQ7@IgzzkdcWC2qUmrRsFYMaYeWDZPQYcZMLuvVvLa3zTZfcRE0s0h7PLsOgyc1PLuQFkaCGL7yjQb9JQQhN8uzMVLWSnZPdHTrxKE8yOn2mXo@6wOtHH8/psInSSOcS03XN@OVBiEDeD88Ufk2PKfQMc0xRriTdWegBaL@vHBHpzDWaVz06NsjxGfd6UKEbd4UkVFisJZMJx2OL@fQ2KA/SDMJf4VzQceuw4dyMinBvRPVWCromXnLZ36tewbBYE9@967uWPWAWkoE4eNx8URmWbwusCzGp0TWWZqqTD5CwZI5NMPD5ifOU7elH7mciBuP14rbliFTV5pkyZUWk1TZR9Suy2Akrceb1xpieX3f9tXUvMFZSw4ArJpxKyJf@9@hv/dFfzcKtSHCRAOzFOvZS@m0en3nKjuBeTdpdnoA8dFTW@5M5ShuISE57Q4szfwuXptS8WHyIUq@NBpDn9D2DdniPcE36Da5txBY0BKGV@mXn5bo5ael2wk1rZF0r3yjtPhoScORjseYJl27G1fp@Kwhxhc@3w663z3Aw/QA24MHeNyB4QTJZZYPL3ts5ZLMbRLb8gYitVRWIsj5ujQe5uQliXu@uo2vbenFXmN/a2935wMtuk@fPnX1Gj1O8MOsxVlrvI4LZDYgj9eDGduWJQ/JpHDZjeP46Lw/HD342MtMyRIR1qQMBNSKYT89x10tyyx5PjF3qZ6UtSiqYX1KpkGQkkpQdQIs2R1N1xERJBzlHgUaiFFvid4e79ZcTpvUaPSCi7DR4OXLpGLWqxiGxtyIu3/LPihcRkNOOSw5v64dh8NnqK099f519VAdvq6p7aPNv6oPe0fqfXX3EJET3h5t7NQ3Ff1X2z2oKSdlI4n8iNhQEl23wmaIpLdqqVh8ohjyZn8wFrmT23Tl/UFwoV73myGuqZ5HwcXLc/nh98LRutSq0XZ0jDPMDufDvOiMYG/BCRxpGwvlpsUOkfB4UFT2lPa0F9jzXvRbnXaHyjrY@w46YWR86FS3QyNI8ta4kXuiJCFXI5sOcQ5WWGBdU/WAyuPuhsAEYn8FEqOEJHds@UoTLv7fd1PwsLb/5kAhCMfm3u5W/bC@t3ugtvf26efbD/XdV0TP@sHhfn3jCJ@44Ju9rfp2fbPKLwSBoq8QHeOXy2h0Jwo@ijNVmp9w8@0PaPjjX@lTb2jw6jpg19BILVz2IH06QbfzW9haWHMuI6gvcEflqwKVm6/uv3pHa74Kf8UNp7kKZvuDzFHE@UPni@o5t0aTZZ3m25qerrTs5Usu30dcjBVSCIVrHDUjx8@eMsDZiKfVCVVmEzYqOPuW4Bo8lw1oaugBwQYoY7BSUZz6a2HBe84g16m1ZrePSKjSmhgR6h@o@tKYmqw5TDFtKwOg8Omo93AeVFqLXxDf04sl3exoKAXU4/iFFFBP5AVU0TpsR9SyLnE52ruEeFYr8uKXi8E2Xwurp/GLjYB3sasaJxk3HtJAxakTEWqkywne5JSHk9BynnauEnF5JD/rdmVihJJ2k2SiXCWybRuVzJCwaeOqQZu9STZrfCVugJ1Q0B5FKldxfXUI46Cw15HUemfdoCcmUInpDvOeWkVUp4r2PO/EKenYS2bQZwZEOsw0HnG9La0VhvetRzU3ploMtI0kp4U1JmjfQmBjCoE/AoYA5VM7nSavVOytCzD9tmblXNQnjsS57e92eWLn1mUzTFXQVlu5Xzq//eZqInupfZKxU2TsaIh@C4ekVvJVZrs/pDnOYpWTeEEKNs/7g1FHxjCX7gHfOPEyR6WxsFFrP1fWU62BDpMt9vo9q9FT4uJbWj0lprxPq8zxcncei68kuzNxPi3CYncHdILT/lVo3Z15uES6DnH8Qoow35Xj8HM8YkxE/3QS2fG7QlLY1cr61sbH/O8/e8gMK2JBEjMbo0P8R4yJtmh68D0fGywOoXfpmWYy@kWXp6itbfC0tMQsN8BoH3jeoX3dy8Za/E3Mjaffw4No8j2//PKlIrXykEw6m3d0nkukm6eOTZMe1zlR2gTEkp2ELMn6nHnjMcxYXr@E1xBGAWGKepAj2LdP5MvTIsT07vSyTZJFpy3Wwx3Dd9U6W1QkOd/hDWSPR@Gn3EZlcd0tJAYlyiJnzohoz0Auua5llsLr1RS4rbvBkfy@P7jVO7GT5eG7oG3dCe27cMsv3g5LliUL1v3B/n4HWFnc/hBY6rt3O2BZJKehxZweM6c3n42tae9u8eepseO5R2Cw9uIEJQZqtXbZ4ytqE1c8JxVcG0yiEB0cbtX291VG9idUl@QetgwtLQYB@4F6m1jbdnos7PxYaYo3y7HyZN6kLNpi/6w7JvNM4t0iKrQO4ml6xMIiiV7e7tyI1NMrC6sQbH3PAtFQLo3dZyODomMN@CvtAQnZZNCsDjozu5mVxacT2Ubgmm6e6Ma2DT9bWMvajWTAw7ENyLYJCs7gWTJ7/N6Lflw27YiChdhO6HCLNGlab2ifcEAND6ig76dH8I5hMUMKI3tRsLOGdjD8KqY17D/PUMxIooSLLmyJda0ca9REP543ag4bJGIZCGDpqT@KRTN9MCKe3zy3B9RNFr1cegkiJRPpYV/aXEHVT77qJYypEa@TlVght@faPGNzbLA8wemshr12e6GHsIVemRQPk02RtL2zqfzfpylZJVItGZrP7Iz5SJBXlpcffwv2ZC9M9fyfhS1ryKT8HF0MaH@fgIzGER/vE@fWdz3zPWGAO0gnpvVmwkxUJFVnxpqS6jsvRjZ@hIucCxEyCMaPjLuTrbrqZgK32dBlRbKhc5GpPlhTOO6ozJop6n@9uzkI5G@29@D725PJhkIwHfwKq/w3/WEUJl55Vhgb6xXc/9PvwuGwx8XEn@kCUHLsxnSnsx1724nBq/QKH/m@ze5JW3snidmtZ84auBE@XvSRZBune2uTx3v50prd1e36Tk094uCc7dRZZGaYcS3Z86DTuwsBlsF8LoHlg334HkZl@o9w8AxIIhN78@WYNu43cWOKkNZ8zNmatFmolq2lydFvR82gh8AnXuZhpDLeD1SRT2Fre9vurJP14lqqPiEXDXo5quVl8n6Gq9I7HOgCUhqEjCbeWwsWPDWMpSTca876sI/CxVZ4I6dnbDkZFEqrxZVnDveu5428i@NnJ96jZiWjaPENehfR5fC69emsf37VVl01@OX0pjn@7Vellp@ox9TW0g8SIbm0UilwUNqn9O@qelZkztUIvuBoz0j67Es2XKUWVLIPX3ugXH7gTXMZHhITXKoeXRguhIvdqHJxvHJS6VWKaxfHvZM1OPmNFiujxdJiDi9@oFWUZIzczB@PTrCm2qeuYe9KIQ4pZ13VriGKXUPozZtg2OnvVHdfpU7joADgCEzbevOBuiTYnoM1G3xP/F54ndPHZJ4CxzpQkJw59goqwbufz5NxHNPqEGY0Kh5ps9EN/zt2nbmifzkY9fmLiToJ1lJfOl@cOePGVOQTBSpy3DGxKeFfQHCSMjlcDMnbsVhR50uirpXgO@laII5Rk8Vh5mMmA59CIKp9uY5PnMgPg@Y5kEBG@S9cTT1/zvnlidUin0/xYMoRDNlhoniCR1yA0J8B3zagCdbcI3b7cKj7@F3Cg7zhM6oR@8mwgbzDmiK@wPxbfWb/Jq7/nAgghJ8TncvXR5xa8yJFUnwH@XABId3SG39cM8CtUgZlDp0FbGmvkgBnS3GmEZrVZKL3c9cgp9CK/qd7kC/xr6luxOVdKc4k4Xtq/SsCLXlI@dM6/nSTajmrWt5UM4UtUsx9kxo46aLt0ZuQptVYbYbdLiEttJhLyIFH9u/V7S/G7UfHaPMkRl6@56e@51PfffkuSCWlfFrgk0Jlu1Am@zkp91VlkmLeVFsVxcqLTyPd9EklScqu3VU28kf9RicpvB4PpXBl/OF56kPe@vLTjNGXLw9SdWIGj78fy3fN30t65GMsU2VfptvHX0cPUMjGs9rWZIJL/V6n@8LRycj1F7BZhqiplFTnJJPKTKqK9sHU4oQ0OJzz87RdryRQFktG4vCcyaw/f5nxtZLxIjeJhngxTk2sGXPEohK3uciEu2GHRWqHPz@wQDBMMJoyM3fdVB7rymMLLEo9MM2KF@TUBKeuTU7xCvwiv@AfM9nTyJly2dkf5wTzG@m8eDenCcRC90FmNpnS0gTuIvJSd@qOVSRpezwJcbaQ2LVOgeM2Q/HBbuMY/EEsJ2xBYSTFFN3jL5rSSYGSYd/bhhAfvzp/KzxyXgWkYw@64Y2qYpsRsBeWk3JwH4XRKELoK47KE10OBl3cOrLCd80u1Dro/9IyrlsSiNbK7jt1WPZIeQ9P2iGdKvlqD5CvYSCSfIguz87gTAYP2P41RCtOXDoj36n2xnKgQXPm8ZK4mYcKwTdYAHc7ZzYSMnIye0DpaBA0Q98hHS0i7ceRrrY7OjUrn6fDbwQR1mhJKzvOP112mp82X@E@92mp@LhkkexKXwcX/cdPEgcrIpL5sIQgiculJ45j3Q035W44D4Ce2sFC/454M7wKe73QqdKKwQUjUlqjcHgVtnzH2Q/jS2DABSvjZhJ@2P3LYVMOd0jpCogZ4SUceXIdRhyGv1if5bq4yXdlnoNLq@S2mYb6qtMCAY3HSbuP22G@sECYAKEHKl2EIyLKI1elUeK7Z40L6y4XOIgiaiDOiXU3EZOh1x91mjQyfJLldAmUXIMkjfVaE5hQe81uAOdgfxYCcI9JKGAQMFdJd@Hg6Evz78JB6Y6ZO/bAjEyBpF@f5wpN93DYIembEJhHhatZuNMAH76uH6iDve3D99X9mqLnt/t77@pbtS218YHvuHFRzvGG1eu9HZIu8W263Jrv0YtM9YBqZviDU939oGo/vt2vHRyovX1Vf/N2p07QCPx@dfewXjvwVH13c@doi2/fCYLa3TtUO/U39UMqdrjncaummpPUU3vb6k1tf/M1/axu1Hfqhx@4xe364S4aw61@Vb2t7h/WN492qvvq7dH@272DmkLHnK36weZOtf6mtuVT@9Smqr2r7R6qg9fVnZ2Jju69363tKzYSsHq5USMsqxu0hUVL3M@t@n5t8xAdSp42iXiE4I6nDt7WNut4qP1Yo@5U9z94GuhB7Z@OqBB9VFvVN9VX1Dkn9w2q0LhsHu3XEEEJlDg42jg4rB8eHdbUq729Lab1QW3/XX2zdrCmnJ29AybY0UHNU0gcyU0TDKIWfafnjaODOtOtvntIa8bRW9g7uDTI74kwhGWVqm4xgWEGgd4Skfb2PwAq6MAD4Kn3r2v0fh80ZWpVQQVYVGwe2sWoQSLiod1NtVt7tVN/VdvdrOHzHsC8rx/UXBqw@gEK1GGQ8YFYhxo94l5jnAgveSRmdQznejycqr6tqlvv6sBclyYOOKhrbmGybb7WNPcRjtg6ROn0cWYQXNgHK@3pV1chAnBOn8jMPqOJIyZt7m3VaEXWwa4yyYcjWnVWJ0Ip2d9opYk/0s9UyJpWeHp51uj02n34mMbV5ODjIjrzkA7JRS6Zj84dWcH0@QpXyGYbjXfVBm10DxoN17tPzRQa36qhj8HvKuXqPiLXBHbeOPgpl4Xuz1OEWv9BX3SyoR4uIFBSqP@DmL4FF6GrCoVWqKvBeR@AzdFRJNcm57hKIdHIzo5IgpM0yScT/Luj2YEr5gx4v9nAOSksI7lQP6J/el@SH7I4WC9IOstxV6GATSyj0fktNM1IIxwSgf/REQk6bW7Sj8Lw01muaDeHPb9/1u@3cq5r6nDZEe0Dz3LuN6qfhmcT1fOT9RlZvnbWaRois@9mFSa@f9YkU3pc/CH3LId/GiP@4xpsJOYDTk25KT6s1oeWuR@kOiySPKVDW8C9ggcZOt@b6o/199jNFZeerE28fx2/l7kFe0GE6qUF75jrnfCf1ydSgCYYx@IgknR0hIxCwapj7E3iwtdU8ByFrjstWP7QWn0e8rpOJCFF9jLo2m1iNR52bmzsSQ6/2q@@2Tja3ibRCWyfrC4/XVlz4rBbP3ry9wPa4Wi6HHVsQOs46Wn8yZolm6T48Eyxgpkn7M8MXCigIOLUm0Hjl4jzENttpC2ZIMjQ3QgZoXow0cuEoENGcQCOB47h15kzUzNALtVVF725CG5YxQ9IV2Ie0MYs3TGP2g3@Aex4@pspHndIM5BmMY4vTJxLuwuWe5ltYyrKmxsO3IMifsbwsYRxi2nAR11sPwvvWv6ledsaxUhMGTFfedi5JiHxYBILZewqejKz33KcEX0AzNHD6M2Pmt/o8YMOcMfh7oJoVB0dEBm345o4p04Oo3WnjzXkE@QNQVA109JzhVN@VyPFc08fJ8eBQazZwKggCQ5sfNOA1@I4IpNNsgXsywVXfRZORfAOwFnTHKt/E@fO6o6Gsmbih@jfJiqFElhxkBOh2nXchmOKfIjjWBhypsj0p@jB8P@BNJkB/zntOAl6Qi0rCOC9KMlQhVa0fWWidK7NRYN1u5FQ0371IQHz1R6Y87hj@vbmRvxriAR6dMbmxQcOe9jOzSAAmBwHG/b8jU3SzgPaOr3MuLo67kl6zYtBTum1wiwVU3DzKyceq12euVvBD1e5ctZkNbhDVdVL2bid8qynLdPEVl49jDICzjXxPwqP@AAknvDMpeditTrJWUU9y4wc0KGWrAWnFUdMIrX06623do@UFSIzJfv1zZchFIFeBz7T/eQEKn0l5rnpiIu8EqtDjoKHmOnYJmPx0SHrTtkQsxsCzsMWH4Ygx8roGgtEV6BzqL4Emso9ZEMRNJJYHSZxBiFuXZ9Iy8vqdYw9n0yCQ2Psj3oSrj@UUy1TwpcAHxpD213eV2@CMaHcvV@3hcUKjw76HmwX0ZgcS@j6yCfT7PeHpDoG6Dfh6HXGrq/e60OHsBddDnX8QlrPOkN9ImGUfmoGapPs3nmZkTj5jFrUGcFboeUzf3CXLkJYiEp4kpv8isoR8xoeXTeHjp2bxZLKPU@@PCeacFhSJuJztaK@fJFSQlAdMjRkCnaieHPBNpvcDu4d4ul33R9@wtoPFajXCltxZFILJJ8FyiDVexzjsTmSrg/6EZ9o0FDgBCSmREkO0mJDVVqjn2p20nZNmSQ6JmKXck@@v52YSY21FDWUMK5unZhvJU@DCSot6dCgcbDQ0tIyozJrw/X11s0YRwtNX1urzMdeLFLKokRUHhrVEU8iN@OnD3jSh/yVhxFmD73BHbdWQYEwdFbcq07LOcYPNgXvO@GwZZ@JkibTCgY4fuOtT7/HvGiODnXYv2YwisIx7QCahc5NgWE0cn/pn/cam/1ucNbpdwLapyHI/Y1IPDyO@REDdjbsX0ecKok/tKxCrXHyLPFlJAwbfsf3kmtWaK5oFA5ytpnCaDiunkuYCD45hxFgkqaV@XswGSMtrvNkOankpP1P2R6v5K7dWvdxaVZludEHAC3g1icsKMSHdMSOSZbz6dpUgdO7Clg4nqq8CtxbLPZSGD8jEvE1TApjg8yUWYLdCezMbsX4uHXjtTgG4RCBlsKtEFl/ohy/9gJkviYp8gKWAmVVWi1aVeUW5QZxCPEwvp3cS0//wdgTAn8C/dLjWdwyixFYxLVNtKVI9is6yijhwuaBHZbRLIlJinXOOj3L/ZBTbNxMQk1/Ht9GDbb8IaVIh9mb4krMyBxtfJDRL9cgkdMYu1hUFtSCy3E7oIJUR7ni7Qwbfst@lic/LnHl5AyCaVNDzllI30aqJlEJuYUnzGttlCWm8rdnzNLSfUdtgoCVWSZnVo7rXMZoLuyB0pH1Fdda/SEJ48wE9bSpx0I06g8W7km9W2XHzMhss2jddN1vGgILs1VosXzUYtJWxngcrzmT@EwwTZpibGlGPITtKz/HbD5JxJtKA/Ot0hh/gw630Syxm4oXlXi8WzL3sShewaLXLDTxlGLcEaR0LX5/3KCON26XIBqmbK8aLDEaEBmNsTxaoCbIFFPp/hRi7tO4T9CjRZRDuy2inT0@txJ10kjOhDw1n1JBLkFPBG6H0ybJpUEbxhcIEycabiykYoXzxhvzVV4pf4ogw/ggAKEVh/nkHEpOcJPBmuAjzg7QzjVgLVSCJKKnddvCIQ76HxOMo/Lrwx1t8dAY50snawLpJoZEuwoudRck429OP48bNwxlihQ0xWeQIu7RlGw6v3@v/mxfqBxBkNr8WVv6Fj10xlWLhA39Y39q3EAHTprSNVMzKj0RGiwaaC7QLuWsG8p2FdpfZygcD@sGPY1oAyGvc/izqGsgnPdKMaY2qty0xijianLLbHNVfl2qJAwlv0F@PRVF1eWNKwEIBWOqXykRBIQ1ZexxKcChd2zOSyGqx4gqVkqYlvSSo6Imdp4zvoOousCTZatEcVaJZzaM/EwgpFjMLpMgQjrL7CIJFFroZuJilXg6uz9JCVKIDe8LxWko9KikaRiPnBCQk2oX3USiHJeUV9QczB@fLLupjzF/89dnRetrcfIr0SfG8Dhfmvy6Wkx9TTW7tJSumqpJ9HDtVlMfiRSujXAsFf7c/9g1xQ55HtuEWpuMlJah7bOR9Jx2mbRv83@J1HN2yjY6hoFne4ab7VdDUqykgrLfHYBdLfCVAWK3/@neGstUg4nOFcBx6YyzS042hKyxZrDUo1vY6ZpIe3GAArOn7bfVu8Pt7VTY19OxMTS6CIfLxWIRTHxqB783ttU4Sur0C@nShfZlt1sYXP9l@O60wLI/DDklQNnsoEMaEpoUkd8fnklmCOBARVE6rx1Zsde/bLftFAy4ocTg0bBJSR0NQfEC1ImNXt4d8gEQg9QL7M/oIPr3s4pn33UgiqaGYq6hqDZMgq8y5vaMyIMXbdhnxzdVDAyC2Vgz0brlVtY/YwVBZhMeLA5f7H5OzJMzr8Nut@@p90i2jEgBc18nK2xv2xWKUgQ3jOzdexlxPFpPhVedruVXjCI2rwOcWZhMngkTFx6x8ffDs9rNIJc5/ilDywp1eRHdXER8ak9lzjKuDhZ/D7DCh4T2vUpfBINck@k0WZiWej2DkyfC6HHJm7n3SRVx@UxM0@zbpUHU2ej6HKyBuu6yLmBi2fPwck9uKR4TN/PxptQGDYsCQ@OEmCv3qwFXs3@cWLwatdv3k4qcBkAG9rskomRC@XMCke8AeAbq6Uf0RBTtv@ZpWm9PBBQRBQfJOqblDio0UMFxHjYrv17nqtWqmh8sLqpqdYMe8nlV3aiqLbzY2FBb9HsDv3@oLC0vr4nM3XI/08sN8/Kr2iAYfMK52DwfbtFP@laB3xistTHE84XKvLc236g8X1@LCsfVDbj109N//sv//M9//V@Fqv7x7/ixwT@Of4oL@b5fmG9@nv/h6xp@H2@dLMyfHs8PThbO1sBlf@Oo4f36KB8k5qP@8NTJyipgvWU7UrPP5ugzuqoyWQIvguEnki5llW1Ghax@G0nmKJax2WZovQ/hR3lKW3iTdGByK09IZAnoGMfxNDrNEAZ4tN4QJQkX2IFKfblbMQf3CAcTF4hvVbI6Eg/rrFchfFqSSArwxaUVK9/pRWEPJ@BXrPNK9xwnoL@dUUPzb@GnN9HZRv9GPfqYU4@K6pGnHmUy/Ke08ozeuvOFDrxzpRhtBzIZj74kVwswM1RRhxU93j9wrp0JcjvOPKfsASQTpoILixecF@/@2FlGEq5FZ84cEo0qOSLhSyZUyX6e732lYflMJb5mUq42rCg09C6GG7NuVOLxhQoURGIIkLR8IQQp96lJ3PSxRzKeCuaNHmuHswkxYJB1/9U2z3u8oLVovqdtnlN7KaQ5YvN5eYu1cU2coRltfJH2EwT4QkW2k0X2JFzILjhi5W31krspXth2/zTzia3DOBwZ23Sp9LuymECsuW3Czfe0X4s25JbrFZXpxNcrVlOZSdtv5VhVLi67o85Auytw65hQn@PWvspMwogyIIEjMfvL0zOMDwpMpKiJYZFkWWPV6qPrMhN62jWdBtj15ebIIkLhpxzN7S8Tc9stsJeIYQfhAUYqNuVrB51upKOuDJnYZ8HwFNkBgzYnVBvJvRmf5yFh7ATG/XaMtM@Q2eQ8mc/UlexgGJxdBJ7K7vYPh8G4TssWaT6jpu9SDxGCCUhg8ummZ3XPICw90kPCFIm7wpZDSF7QHev0aDK2mdjnBENqpoIOu4JJkGInpmT4JTVWE3RMuPo7BsFGeUp4x7eRWsSy5IWlkYaUsd1meJpNTR3HtGDPnXjiZBxBNZ6Zhhd0pUsstBd88UuSvIsYAbrtjPYC1K4IK8/QPlans7AXpBanQdcxjv6FNSXrIuYzp6IUayRHQ3laSjLeASvSI39KR4GQtcmEM3Lmcrm5j5FO55a11xEO8h3b4hcC1YkT0HECM/YMUUe9jgjLiRUqyYHhqzpb/hOEdjc4I/zG18EYrPgxm3vxoOAe//Sxd/Io97H35eNvLmOiRbJZZfMqqy@zjcTSc4VWxoKX@mms0iITavBjL13gY0@JD4tFAkKkkDv@qXDypUAIfcy67qPCx6wQJDVkwKRwd3sFgC9MoZlNY1HIOnPuI9cMfu5FyVW0tvJfjKG8cOUvYWE2lXxMT/ucYZtAsZ/ur5fichIVVpeKT5ZKT2gndBbe5IfhJdbbfHR5Gt6QKhFhO0tLz8ffUtyQIsTXmyhYo5c31E9JayK@J5F2UtIiVE9zbseJ2Yrq@MITVJ6ozOFS4eLixmUCXD5iw@8pYjlTlmNBiemgxX05rJ9R/wLtBBHk2qR3iHAkrAzERoSPUPOAbJKv3MahrpkuC@zn5KtNxG5lIDS8hay1WvT6vbxW1lx/YQ1KNLxmuqvF1eLkHJ2aoqkZOq@VqYUHqrT@4ul//Nver9lRdn2p8H5If0fZX7Mrq1l5pAf69dj8usquZ5@j2MrX7LhAe2B6fPof/5vqr/@F4ODL@Dn9s75sYK2Ms@v5Clf5kl1foYfS0hK1@3/@@Z@pD/OyY0Mu1vmGpxixNUORzaDHvEvfVR29lG3pQiJW2DELMMTCkPbm9AOGUTdLq0U@pstqq4qrUEe@MvYoeolnw6wRmwrJSYaxpyDNSCpU0EBeQBoTiraybDeM2QaYN0FT/fzQX4loB/CzNueIm4xNNx5GMBmal20RDWBOWqT9vDysF19kYvOOcsbYlKwZFRJbOy1rVx@vETu87YejTjNtJWGm60UzuA5PffChH7YuaU/Vi7r9X4aFK2LJi9LSaqGNw/0C23EXBgwpPxj7v5EiqJMB0caQjU49NaQR6F8ghJfH2YJIod@O76RMPknSsgdhU86w0jmJqYj4@HlyPYzu@IkqneN/SYFH5kydCNLKlfaxRzX39ssqsxgXlHK853WBzVs2jtUhMPJiDTtg2eQ73AecDpr@@NXhGTshcS1EXZciftBqNQL9LefMZUyqNM@ZOw@7g0qmLeHdETsVNyaa/qJm3gol38EJQj7Pgg6wLsJRQFv0SobfYD@etIAwKfquNQ4Vl5C1rcvqXX2rwllX7mj6Wpq@phGFlpC0E/OMFY1N2cVEtlRwVDkMG7hSm9kwtRaZpM1Dn/8Ag0iGpd6GW4LuDntAEtWS7mirMnvYPN4LE49ch@KzJ0eLkrnaySbOj54pIR7U0J3Qri@NkYBAFNwyLJTp94F4QFRMmtFOz5F4fhOfTXwPDYb7sIdQonbYOgk@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@m5TGr9X0AgQxglCfJsVCzIvvc2ySJTjZg4x5Cl7OlC0b0TedKOIAc7qxjKstSrkQZxWYc24BiHObYkY6UixjRPmxxomXZbSRzFG8onE0oM2Q451qOLMkp5lgq9tIAmAj67ihBfpf39301FaN/tl@v@VBUd6o/hX9jlM8345vSeNbKqv6thkCO1os29zCZupXuCgRsxR1wNgEQQjftmRFDJOoAbX6tqa9TOrj1Nw@SbgC7BpoJdycjupJgkAvfAYypzfvcSgOdtfhd2U5vJqWNHFIFT0t5Ijr7olt0WQuaTWGJKS8B4ilSRBxoJaE2@cShhcLdNa8A713MYxd357N0ymWlQ0Vqe3bBSJ7mmdvpcxdbLGk2WKpjHG8iy@Yb@/kjdOw3de@aDFzfIM3Hvwx3sjfnzny/y2Yo/aP4Y7HmjselyF7hDvisOHs0clp2PszOOZ0zGtwo9U56@B8qG39RCeKngWABR4whA8pfSwV0bdbxInKzf6wOLkewUhoaRmOAX@o809055@UIXP5cSv8r9r5/N@588u688tlrDUzRl6rdla49b9PjxOVMJd@MXN4oe5KMfeP9nRF93SljNV0xjD/f@9p/v9RT5/qnj4tI2KCXDhI@Pq7uVk0kerBZr2emFv4jg7alUMe@9lc6WLv1apkaPPQ7l5G5xVo6@oP47@q8V@FNOInpKHDXURsGxrv5WV7Ks7yolnyKYeCk5X0RPprIqNb/dULVrIf0QuUCGk@2BrqjQop5J58TG6b/ER/TKRvvPjcF2eR7TpZJi7OrQ207AhLbjLFRfPVSTKXVuJ1ZYtjIKvNw/2dxf8hZLgIPmkvNEIeQ3sddrtmJbG3YIdx1CndGas7gH2g9xwpVtHkZGRH2ts7Zpe526UaB7aYWBdnbxLkqg33f7SXuoC@YWXlxpER0cbX9c2uCqa5Znshb6jvUmh2l3WP/xCXPtNc@qys9vXG4DZSBfrAT/Nisk9bWl6@aw2QWj7@YAIWPSp/x6z6vw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/i49so)

Command line: `rfunge -2 polyglot`.

rfunge is separated from cfunge with `001kk1`. I don't know how it works. `kk` is another [source of incompatibilities](https://github.com/tjol/rfunge/wiki/Undefined-behaviour-and-known-bugs#k-followed-by-k)
between Befunge-98 implementations.

```
>001kk1;@,,,"370";# _"582",,,@
```

Answer (score 2):

## 372. Befunge-98 ([stinkhorn](https://github.com/asztal/stinkhorn)), 16294 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."4F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $p/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@   @,,,"364"<\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<      @,,,"369";@,,,"372_"^ s;k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@  @,,,"368_"z;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk5mnjx58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@9w03N71FBr77OTRo@u@WfY1ybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrZwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//0YZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@x1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79nPs4EBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmOfgKpwvXSoPiDRjE6hX9NblQ1g@JYkuEvoRyXBAEXGAN0FOQM6IWiZ5XKvo7NL4B4uk2Z7XBUJVBJVzoV5GXYvzMtHBJYlWl@ZZ@G5XXJIkVENa4DRqeY0SCwh8D0xQQlF8FAUf2xFD5L2eBjJNdxzatM8HEtwUSTJLkLhFwaABBXGBOHD7JqTti@u3LsXCC4btRoQG0hTwDZ7yahGG0xYysCpIbJM0oifiTxxjifYNxJJqC9GvuKlAbEJKLVWZxeToQs9jt6vBIgEaBVspOQAsX47f2qeTnvXG9pGT4wkYq8DocnsTsSqAIM/7w2127AaX8IqaL1xxCoSL6Yn0DeIl3yxQUU/mmt4KP7W/KJEWjiBJfBpdSWKeFLfb0HQe/Ou5YsE3AWdnXOjDhT/1J/IChlR2pcJgk57o6dyINgdOBz2bPfkcc3vizxQ6Zh2ZcnDcrq6Rd6bGF0M0j45eHC0e/Tz7RUwLLNTue6hmLlSAYfa6Uwa2FMlJ2uVzSiMBeCH7dthY8LlOKLgBzPJmUVEpXkXBpdZgM7Do69dRwlIQogOygHc@Lsm0vA4IHQJHd0bXhuE2SCVgizDJEFcJh2wAGbowKJjuB6U59n0zRtsvOuFGvv@WDJrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8JoAFQZ0@HxEpLUihpo0LDQtXNGZQno9Rar5eGBKlIyTz8eGj/aMagfXn1SSKongTkKV0tycDzVtTUMFXxQH2B64uS8mLgqM8TWVdieBudwnBi7Zla@ADANR1ZIdJ1iiomjeEsu9drxv5St2QAuidIFyXK6PyUPdDCxopBw5xXVR5V42iFLAYrEKvlSNWGLo8bHXzeaOYK0eHre4iz14UKC0KwDgQyI0uBJ16EvrICynSF6v94h8/uVFwj4RIUAWkoGSexWTKy7ME1F4kk8U9ZQ80NMcy5M@J44lMTCpKPFgXkLseKZ@R@Pszc5LIJPlTTUJcyH1390B7GET2p6xpJoOUBtTFcWRy@7i@1/WARmzHcgYO24I0XDoMMgSxaW01dweOfaOFdPTEqsZwiRD4L07c6GMYa8w3pDhSqqi6yhcbdds7By6tFrKIJMIQgVIovvxKP9MBXYt6Hx98Yx8GETWfyYTuDF2AgkgaQhe6uhFf8mASZCT75VlZwXC58EZvDwKkyHodVtpndGHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv7KIn3i3MD4K2d@jbTAh5MWOCIoO/j02ZODT/ef7n7RnGj5/NJ7LlMuAOIgvw7IQvKQ4w176xbvmlgtBBeDvuFi9wIuMAUFJVgtmnouMG4Zo8i8AGuohi@0Jj5xhnbcS16vzDmGSq/sLiehp9j5eFQ/ISjaPQuVEZevVuN4jvQznEzGXkVRoJcPpx0ZlFblVdex9IFC6WBgsCxFRdXl4BDnNbxVKaAw3tzgKfjkFogOc5pB1K2RA8oLrXkja2AJDp5mrSxzMARdGBfGDTcphxRMtVF6oCGArqyEdSMGTG@AW/8ZtJPISfurqlbidK1mtJwiBtGWuj/E3egboDolYLQCVCSvvbLmveY9NgcujZCuA4kxeYsmOTyGY4HFQJCkWVPU8wPkELfA@VLkFYSj11OczQUupeQzuaJayCugloGaBjKrhHNu0kifdIfSxJEAnuT0ad4gQoV9r6vbfXnLdwSFBbnvI6hqtvGi2bRbIKA371HZcN25MW811Fayym4m2fLjJ6tAvUvVQ9oNPIB2yQmkSU@2hp/19JvsrKdT7@oxZTIa@2OONGZPd0GQeuMAv@4Z0b6HCZRooLK1FFfByG@VFRNCFiYV8IaYUqBDwUgLpKdguSQQelE8BMoBvhVJwBazGbwefH9HhI@g0o10bzpxj9ZIUK7B2VJvDEikyeYucmkP5wcnMDqGlI9cGhoXmTQ7N@I4j657fLYSEvlr/EF60NVCCDQrH85I2@GuBiACSkXqOXAOoCucNh0uZhlR6QdKgwypTDj5ABKETasHA@AzkJhXZJdXhOdEPstVOrWdcxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17rNXrRuED2r8TgAjSoX4eu0KN4xunyWlSemWoASqLORMXJwKgGkK2IFBlVB5wvqqAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfY/T3gYl2DzxdJI1SigKT2WXziKrvSNxRdegPUfItshZWPNLHf6CcBApa3N9AsiT8DStKJM6JIn9N8CwY@CMRdAVcMocZAYaJec8aGfV3n4xphIlmlbQjxOF8EuohvbGzEK/F6PA2uHXBto2sHXSlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/VvyqEUCeJVtIAzOUHN6Y44TeqFSyrbTeUP2nhs8kNAVgHmJL@AA48WSths5kUqyf45oNyO@Ruu8h7Rx3XXPso@ATEAj4u4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jirrp7RgZ1VxQGg0UMRNuvNnINFvNi2Yv1byKpzF1sqrXQD8E5jVJjOSB60zHILg1chUJeFuyka20qp1aPBPfSiRKkgUZ6cnkR6VkSue4TsQNoKlEsxkHlPrYaXSHLsGbpbVkMkQUlKNvgpZhWYm4fFGC/DvJVjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7zQgqNHlcYZAU5Ej8wZoBI6Jgxx0TUFYpC0OIXd9RvGeDh3oxHCWTeQsnEGfbFXBbf0IBePcsk3PH1UoFvS9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs85dxd4SZvK0s6oYNw9k/ojZ6Irn8mgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNpPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3ZDgFZhlsT0sDVZljwegOHRbfvA/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDryvBDJopSCS6WgHRBG4pM4Iu0FYtmZVQqBGc9wdx8vjB@LYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMClEAKgXZP0Z48oR6sSx/QzNeNdQk/lIY0VLxNAzjiI8vRCbecXUfWg8ajSHrQzyHJkdETLOAffWCPMm8L1@gpWwKt0jruEEYIqA1yYi1srZEfoDjeuCdPZpBUSOCAGw3k2h0Ineesp2laoZvvV4IwpApA9hAaCbVSG1TcIEhSITDpN/I@nxYKdPRPDx/u87kTGmxxeMV5tPbI6U1BrvT1piPDHqTZPtCTaTsjE9AQpH9zah05zoRr@fCybmaGK83maGrpNOdzfVrm1nRdp@NYNBV0W9JF/Knr6ZbOJ6GC0N3PnoKs//zkuCZXIpEU/Wx0a944D7k6W47Pg@iaI623BstDHidMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDYK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjguSnuhauR/Nun3l7yz5H0qIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xGiR8jwSbgxdihMFVKA44f7QtfGKFI/vbpHDlcWn4SaEoWEFS4tHILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHejfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVygYpqJq0sH@jquE2DY8m2wVKUhU8BdSJmZaRmrPifusyrniEhj4Tm83ZRxntC9BLcLfk5j1lYFRpj9MafFWDkLgvw3bmTAKJD2PxievuEPgMS82WUQntM7X7jtWT@CoZEAzj@hU2kL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2fN@Bea9L6zQiR3aIhIOg@F@zyNH12yRow5J3J3tgyJy12JU@c9tDfKWVf31fKZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdo48/a2RaHIIw0nHlq8RbcRZsTwbBGQQl3EcOLtypMzEnJAnQTgQT66vKUKgZLZJA8QEGz6DKwoz8GmHRL43LRV36BmiqCQNL7s1HaWYkr@S@pU8mhs1pji8/rkc3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8OgiFV2fPJw/@hIBsr1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNZVOsBktPIV9lEvzj7CNElU2wXoaqB9tP30QNRVIHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6CcL9Vd0I4CoEljCTUiYBVVpb/uc1VLb@cFaD4FGES0J24VwHcmkl5apuvZQ8GGpJbIUqcK6swXtQ2E8TFNtWkv6FuhEvHoGGR0Ag1aDSY9Aa4HEQWWatV5XsAIC4qYO4AsSuK1BS0i72mBk1fA28QaQiCn7z2lr1oZKRyK7W5ChRtLvM3oPP6R@AihGXQnrEy280E9fcbHZmXga8Fcs79nNTpa6cvKmyTO0Q@50zRgw1TxHRof9XyPqnlXVjQyZCV0FQMViRgCTH/eIBPsxROnB90HkxGHokkuwiRriHK2eUl4ZBtaoxwCC6V8ca4CrRPYExPHKjNE/9oQFQ6oN7qbyTBPtsUxEDNWl6pxRAuwitn16RT6UyMpuPSoWmfOrTeE7raGVnNo0QYph6dWjdT4iZUui1FDcvA42rrSueNOn26rYhAyx7@gjp50IS6LwuDEKkrR/SgufUVOS9vIlnK1t@eSiMtuJn0@o6YUrlEkfudjrkuKiAB94UFzxXRgEkhPWtyTlaDswY4FQPjETAurr0sqn59/xFbwru/j9Z//udv9gD/N1tnCAMFzjyGjjYM3dhSUn9tY/lJ8YVuqxuWT5BPLVMnxJDrLpBd3YUq6VboWA2aFuElCYb/ES4p@C0OtIk3kBpvITNecr4iGDxXZ7JqUc0GltldF/fafiyeFS3/gGLXIyRwIcg0KBGxLt4IxowvwURUbGRjdxcq2DTFiJh5uw@nkym/g@B6ZyOaY/zd1jf9mJm83lENhe9cv6XJXf102nOk8ekglFMLK@Iuak9rwBKIA/5ycBudq6vPK8h3ggfPddEWQ5tyTo@7qMKzp95Y6pAW3uNv1BFGt@TgWvy@LorpH94LHeuxZlp0e09K9KEDofi7IRTcaypFkGZeQ7Old@Yogww/nMrCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0qrC/w/WOVoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatRI4DUndq6e7CdQuJL8oRLCOsm5H2h41nZtcBcWDM1KKsasHQERkwiGUGW@MWGeF2YrpFtj@Yq9AYHCeRQtdqFuB0J7hldA1NvQdD41s1cUNshEhkZx2mus45/taKD0NQTfl99Yj2ZmWp3oM5SVbX0mEcXzscLE0O4uTjHYR6bnoG3VYj9nRlQSdda6X/chcIpv2i03h3kbVnWo7Hjul@G4IGLmCB31cTdBSXpm5LNBkedd/Cg4I9DosG1a2BYxVKA0WH29pWn7p95Pv@8305XMihVPUODhWIP46t@s@1fP1UcU/vaiA6sOji/taI85YhdhWb8tde1tcOFANcuFtds0eZEqWUFT7VtyZjXHI51@fB82cYOtahNhg6xnMSp0G6wwTlEjgmLhexf5bccrfn1ns/pnQDbPGuSkQa99QyYLCi@40mZVpG/cAUaibz/iyqb02NqbFS0TjsvDLwWP0tSsb7FyrjV2PTn6nHxQE8mhLGeuNrhu9Vahyn8e1WZqJbZte4W5RZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdNxMMbCn46VWXdLO7KPbUTYcB13a6S2VDkM@lA@V7pCUluRzz6DfrRoT1/Bwg1gtn8lkfAEmsuKy9HKbJpUN074y@X0pY/JZ5LyIi6tsbsS5Og9CS3QL4loWpK1T7ClyuazYpm1M5nh/T27acRzrQ1oKmCoeGHZAW5Voq@1tLXZD3PEPkbDF1IWHEx6d/rpJCz7a@Lol4AeV5tsaPbok9F6tKeGi5wgXpJZfb5@@iSww3ZULHm7FOSG@@dZaL0v6syGqXJKLt/Y6LqE6HcPS@WNWyN0Gryxnb4W3zDT8xVpc3OVLuoul@Ng1pjSeA7LMHmgpQ2Nk0OstUr7eQxMZ/mNtpJmDv3XBM8PoKrN9o7suwtgEvmDjfWkNOSIsTRwb9KsJ7vNDPcXCnaS@7zoOHKz6rUTywUgfGNxmy22ccjFhgbtpuFq3cK6euqjwHTRdSLYwxrGeJKBTnRpzL3iuBPh03oV2nY7unm671vm7OAf6Hr193RbWm0OsPXSG9tAY8n3j4du6zgH0OOE2dm4rOpR6MMStbOPx0hb3KD4tx7LeB5/IGjmjdJz@yjLt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PmAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjXPKNgZOpzs07yq0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a6IGZNJD9FbtkxArzuXkV5q0fBjfBysa3R/9ogPa6HjFnll1QwdHcuWxvpp1@OzoehiFZwQjvRGfni7QsffK6@n5mQBNLKXKZze5csS6FhXdn/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tiLZWSkI4CuWRkQOBR12W7vM8t0sWyWX5bV6BoLalEkX0pH4Juf@8PzQ6akXlb8F@ir6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491aNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBTTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohx818tTLtN0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr5wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a66gCiLZVduL7oT99anumV@fQs3WERtabODLkG70aD@@rYD3VB@Y3cdLDREW0kewv9OTP5bIH71utsX50PRwR1PouGViCkmOEzFSXRv0hhUxr8/bh8YqFh2IH4NcGXvV3LoznuNpsTm5bptWNyc0y@o/16mO6zaB3VqI8@loPPX8x@oy0J6p6Cz06JT8vXMTgEuvgbWyoW5NVs9UR6ZcQQrzB8WFc500/g3TcgbsG6UMA6ENhDAUzlcQzgMYnp/hhhzXXkGJlPd7LnviRIfk8oq9hrY1skwybXNy@2zOZIKbc4InVoaPHHhCQXmCd/n@h0KQTlZj5Mndsv7iaPId4ztQ3rEzdbsGOkN7I1G1wM/V2At2H@OJDgftpZxHtbSuY0H3Aoe1sst0HXs6kdypfeuoULh1VKigtakIGbDE1/efPk9GqYF2a98lhQb2yBautRsGrhGZaYMgtp6PLscOdImH3E7SEW0VviPNLhpz6hK7fuis0neezWEAeW@FCZj/dPTQ6OKy4Z15f@o8dWwHRqMxMMrRkcHP/C9t9FidEJM9wVPtgJ/endkcE9g1gxCXNvSx0YH2tRau9xmLOOCH@kRfMxTR3CDpf6HrTloxrY7hvqJJv4h7nUq7XKDHxox0i/UEw/ugNOl2uUiM83FLfWRpxcYbO47N78RtM/BQn97OVWAooNv7L5TLuBF/aV5gpX62XNXDM75LxOhxoxTr6uoaHcfi91v2JNkm3xOgu6bhKU/QxgH5FXJMAunLu5WHFG/lIQvVCCTZM92jRfrVqsYCpDr7gC1AQ93tOrgS5jtu2Z0TMUxwB5sO9/bzjQMdQPwMOJbenfrGQu8qljXqjOi2VmGItOaR0cFTQR2y5jHRZzcbk88M@aYMIju6QgMAAbvCTl1giWegjSTvHraW9KhlrJpjuhGnXrtcTpt1JNs0um90nDVzCF@LuemlcKiz8ik518xVR7oRzSIrOp10X9mTlreugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xum94OzKysWA@ZjgxcZF5ehVkrujrekCrrrF5PD5mra0i@rT/gJaHdPy4fSrtrJU8ED/@HDz5RYBBuF3KB6RFgXXev4EPhp67tP96HAp853qRvzg6h3HgKYB07wWrlIQk8eM9A19a6SkDr2VOLzz4MIvuuRj1SxySywixJFrHriSEZ9plEhuBmN2vk8ENfyi5a750YPcm3g4ArDdKT4PxXGM1/rlhAjfJG3OypKhyxs0LO3/65CrnnAWcAecuZSGOPnsrYe3bw5PBEHnvqyvFpd4inI27IcUuGFbRSJjIl9Up3I@udfDtaz/QmyoNjVdp7ciBjhDX45isaEjxwZW7psXbeM7DiquhrtSAMNSarBcTHJ0@fpBZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47Pk7jSZNPjlcGR1M/gt7Rd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfk@t2l1cB33XJHTOkgnBmijQIyPuV2WO4WrrjM2eifzsfEZDJ7Iwb33zL6wtpKf6mfmAHshK69FFHVUVpYLuWRkZzYo24YbPte156k5Rm7ZpYfCH2u3o6DkkFXc7Grp4bYV/@tSDMv4OxE@LJGauUmtUTvCiu79fQumquo6PB/rfWhXll/bWMsRVq0PW87ZeywlG77yIoVe0gSoSjLv3EdelEbAuhW84fS87wnOztptMLcBCL0LKzv8uWHPdVuitazbxIsKpMZNbbdG@YbxHgtS4Q6fMzRWvnKNL9xSzxJdcibvyPjEjSTZ23twcFeCIx@Xt8f6@NPn7JnuoRGS2yNGS2y8R4kXktErCeet0ALe2uXUngugtFvhDcar@3OFHetuz7Hns7sX4egMKg7tZFw4hIVvFMmwzJm5aqzq8nmtZ6u3Gd2VNz/E4cyX5OCocRof0Ltv/zNVzWTI9BA@1Qx/vaNlgg7OEujS52jPLhp0chCyhi7KLTJ4JFdqo0@MGW5H4bPBq5T6leNb4Zaxr5hcP5zcFla6JSx3S343wtCTZeWMegvA/C1hLC@HwU8c63zoyHu6a3gr9h@vLNBtFSnfUpFyhDv71tJpYdF3rxfx8eiC/1hJrSfGxM2Nh07HzK2sw24fjUyyp2gs/Wa4v51Cd2l7y8Dxj3zw99X5nU@NlRk91d@sDiBOc7oyCJigMZzSkYibwcsLpB2QeQ17YHL7iuyBM9mnt1sUs/DE8@q9COb44XS8vsTAG/GTFNfZ@VLEz0Fnds499gCPxi3E9BW6P@6PW@2/TqZl4cQgmhl9fLIbUNfhsaJFclyU4otnS954eHRyeBzxc43ZbJ3SK83W6ZArQxa5fnqSW8p2u/7ibAWy1p83AnED@HH4XCsHcWb3yfFNloDq23AysoKQT3R7MWO61GA9Z0InDVcGPpvPaBvlypYe8l1sq8Lc7grvJcUeBmTThLw9pd1Gy/rt9jqqPDG@oLUHEIPYhIslHKhveMmY5YZBCSnJ2o7qnC6En6XiHo@Hpj1bGTRal4Z2kSZeeau7wS47tpxz9iS0KrSOPWirgetnhr2OOa06rCiVs7dLYdlrItW6duFfL/Ef65rkwTpB7RrPwA0Rt3ETTH/UVR4FL59pyTvjf3IcRL877p7l4Px9z5yO7o5MYFOpuyO6t7C/6wDNu6Phxz5Oh45rr4jKzwoDqUXtzHtp31IQP1vPTzR7cvAxgETChlokl7@8FD2ejdaYE5tojXSTjmJD3MtLtuEff4YAMThQ7R/4RqOFpj018MQ2/x7LpLYJ2dRqar7MdvBTRxVQtpKUI3qRabggrwbbvPDPMlcq6hXbqDGxIjL/NHlo6ZlbKwa4aGcV6sSkU5VtTiBkMzgJzejDG@yS0QQOaIxqPgNvshK1CVH1z4pDkTYvnh082z8@2T15ftzItK78s@RBJWwbcgssVnyU7YlQdx9tIBhy2@Vkw8CC7OijIDjx4wX1YvihoeWq1ZaqtqiUuINpNi9sW1HoOL0iXUH5JJHnRqHI3sCLww5qTO3jW1Ko8JPtdEAfmoiDFilPaLMKy6zKeKyDkLNp@@HXv8tFofjdtgp@uQ0z9s1NAyEOHKfn5@gZ7O4ryPHR7sGT50f7LCjggmjOzd5kWCvnuTVybuID2qlv0v7CGov7SeLQVrVa/FEcEBOX46xCBhDIEjjQOUQLsIOmE/zUWyyxSfABg/GwUZT//E3lKi7jVvkkxI0HhYpDtkDyRCgbGxvsBIiEPTw6@Gz/iGH59x@SN6IIQbATPH39Zz/q8W9pBNaRgm/WuSOSSMi6jBC1wBCYJVhYTkCcU9cdr/9yHX27guwThB/NCL/6Iwj0TRWg23MybHjN6F2S7FDxL@35NgmDjIiEAvv7uCqD9gVdj52ZnonWEbAMfTT3t0zsuJGLTFzKbBc/y4cf/9Ppwy5Q9Kk94Sa1fMM6MaA0OWQ5abZJheWfgREjEePbG0DsHQOEVebZJog@kwp7BZSIKx8Vbj1DkurxG0kC0BVySSjgRCLesA/oKU1Xefer/0QZVBm4J@D@ju@eZR7A2y/7b31w/wp3v1CQ0G7aE1yUJVogtAHq14AXJMQ/4j7yNUKbWyxZIA7NHgZ8lZkjaKYzwjpG5znwuwTseAEn0fgMGg3IDVrMt1TC8zPcVgKNkFYUBUkKFSiZzokYM75p85ox0kK@kFMVKKR0FgCkrwcM8DQ6B5hMVqCbCGfmuPYShPLt7W0m4iyKUStUecsqm/aLrPgyLOgmxBXOh1i4BoM0kGSRAsLqfjIYfFJqEpMi94qrcWRcPQdGJQrH0QvfbR8RIksAsjiODDRHP8MPV05AtvCN6nbwU4@RL8ts@oAkFcYkciVFwbfx8akzAfKBTrr4dhS38YGblvkIiNYqPf45V7Jli/Qo3@xZi6PpwSds/L4mIw/goLKZ64NptG3FzxHEMYKoiKvIt/GCNSdNu6Vw2mRApj9cQcw2uH9JGayhWV7v3ZuWTBPX7ZAistj9Y9vB6aJHUBmW0BQtq6iF5KJKudzKKvk18rOB6qC5pEvIDtgUsIyuYb5yxt7u3v7BJ4fPjm9Y66SY8evRgO/Xt1NNSU43WqEjHq3WcpM8eKQcP33wKGiIRaELEW4MjN@viXpbTRazwAhycaroetVWlfB67daX@HNud@B6ebPabUWjRDfKoWY@IF/a2S89ovN51zPXSquwlc/fVqQFPCUCeo8frr5R1ETy4qrR2q437Vj8JiWs6AgvYvIWdgJwNb2tTQWJ/WblsGLhh5ZP8BN2XrQvZlf3RXEzi8bg0LbDxDldmMvzPSIBkfoG2QCLFGQliLq29x1yGX1h1FHjH4LmVuSiNrIiBS5kbsN4BNRJ8E1p5CILk7S@Ndah7g0tsyMEtsm4VdbAeGRokJXbFUskBf/DJjzjhP@V6VllJtM2vkQSuR3BSrPbDLwG8JICdGiU7p5NQZN@5oy5oXvarvHQCFxHDrDfh1M@vWOwT6YjiNenx5FBS2fAuSVIDJiMh0XlshRwCd@@6yyFFnQhvwZaefUrLo96@cQsKQ@NWc8cAG9PJNPA0T5S1RYLbcBipcnmqx0Xqc0WrXBrV/wYj8xH0f5BhoBniwLoDV027Z4xS8TP48lKC/JH//j552fxpLiKlsggsW@ht3fdMnFY/KJ6OyfRJ37vDMz@ruIW5fJNLgF@1wFzC3nBV7bKZXnoCfTVxBpK7scT9wk4QYxI9Ef6mCWmNrcuKDN6TTQTdprMrkl1brnUZqkUKVTwoACZUco@ufj4ndDtOUsoNfywJvh6dg8fb8wxa6iy3AI3ZZJkm/j1uz2QuNDeZlIAHRiSVAhsDUkI1AwoEe8kMidwSIPhEBceZKNxRTB9DIxWGBzECdWa1e@xyNcMlyVHsVyu@A26zBXLDKjvJjuUFQB7g88Fcj1g1zc8BDgD9VcWYgtGfpPjxSjfGC/IY99iERQnFrE2HBgyYgBrYQu4O3Txl9i3oa@AfFCpPD951C4lFZGFlo8GrtnDFTBuMD9U8fxPHEE3VZaixqtco/sYk6GNyTY3rYSmDh9RhxGvsdRYFA2@nd5AWfYWtKmqt1K9n9BvBYiZwwHAPyHaDsChXdBgamxF2Gpm/9OfxlDYSGyq6mnbPUvF85kq3NRqnuXZR5tNSdpsZGr3N3XQoiavZ03QyZWt3MMzY9jvHQyUpiiyLMspytbFxUX80dYz80WeFaSeqRVez@ZX2UL29ewqq5Zen47VQkN@PWuJpVr6tMWePfvibfttUpydzV@LzYQW2zu8FNUcqvyxSpld7BSysdMyqJ@QL2On7A1cp32G/@R@04u4dXR3@qDCxkUWazYB46pYFBWlEW/BP6n7L@Hiin@jLtflndbbt8mGrk9mc2aa5tjr9eDnDEGC1JLHDPTle8DpeQKFNelJGhReo1n/5nxCnrHZrjEYTPf1uoaHh@X77ercnD6aPP3G58H1HK83R5Fkb/zP7aZSCUlqrJinqLT1fAw/3PtnP964Sl88a2//2bdGirGBj0N8fOfqKbqP1fxHGxsfPXiQy6U1TePuZ9949vO7u7u5h@n8s0Z@JydlNrb/9E82NjRtW1M2Wp6ntuKN09MvRC2TE@U/@514@9mzr3tePft/fvNtXcVbEW5nrAh8Aq4sU8GJ9xL8VJSx3veKvYkBlauxOf21Y4H/xQZT6zvF//K9w9exSayuKZ@78JzEXscKpRh3ggPessHbWawe28ZohavYXKnVauAs/pd/C@nrnwAcDJlvw62eD2AV5rG6VKMkl7F6ARyqpkG@//c3vxkpIWcTNRLjgus@a8Al5oqauNOCa4uubQEtSkoZRQni2ZPhxHCYWrqn3sMXE17gYRtomt@YNGP46XJ2eJ@xo0YqlWrJbQku@QVNEimqqjVV9R6wA@mjrVpN2mLcZmY2m7@Hdr@TNKU1cGDENO59/g9xxVZ5Vn9mcEdCrLBx/@XDeh3qlK1nt@opuvyORH2qWBId577I0uxlHFSQRuvlE8YN/dbFTEkT0@n0/Ta9zxBX0iykJLz4PRYLfbDLsut@S0kgiu8b@/B4sX28/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PsPaHLT7pl9ZQsinUGXqMN1v1Lp1uti3RUvmvheBzrKVEqVktK@aia2gAO1jpia@fgyns/Gj/lnxVXGmklKDRdlW/ezx/d6bOFd5z71qJ8fwCOTB/NrQY4lrJE7xNqNeDC0@puTpcZZvSWhQFSTGmoh35J4qnpwlVnjPjSTqBXLYquu5bVDdr894xcbbnrMiYFmWAjw6Je3vqhbPQxZvNWjXrF6kKy@iPOh8cLyCrFGQ2kZNCAEfuz@RmWjVClUNKVdX38BaUZfKaphGM@82FksvDhmYwuExkLSvO4XNEX4wgIKZh8SDySj92G@1ErZgipWfZfWZmIViETLStqgLWZUMextOL8P1wb80T9c4SveN8jH96YoN68NVlG3tKyS/6iwr@H4escVLasA4wTrdjqdN90OSB263tG7ujrRp/pMn@uTzrQz60y60y7DLrM8o5918k7JmTFOgLIUy@bVzdg9Iuq3jQ12xLlQi6WCq5m683ouy23fSQ4Hf5LkzGJC7B/gqquayrZgfMrADYQycoLOjH@qKrAYCFoXrbdbjbdb0EHrqW1ijq265JcSHnL7fislXV01wF2t@v/b9dBZpYu7oHKtq1Rq@0UdpI8X9UYKQL7wQcoSI6Byu97appAwMz83P3i7BfKLlNpubNecPfrJ1EGkeM6JF5z7LQC8vVTY@/dTMrjuA4D6JvTHZCq1KUkbODY2/LECIrfqqaBWWIYESAsXFz/jDxQ96MVX21f1q8b21dX2Nvxv0/3Kf4Lv1faNf3osrjVxFuEtZC3NhlJvKk2fWbTgXVbq6CMrTXDU4QnxGlmt1GqgAy659d/mv5xe3EMfLHJLhlILsS22FUMDkNnYlhB7@e7L/wV/zXdf/j7Kiwz@jIoQu8BurWyhtlnmSifcmP3UZk/5ZYMbf8Er@qDH0zp62vxm44KUoryUWYXP@SfUUiEp4wDcdvpttCkhs5cQ9QbvY6JWKojtlDrXWGxbLBSJ3f3cjSsej/@jl1q5GOcTNWgU4aXneU8jpVyUEyJXtYwqqZd1bveff6Ll51Zd/@jn1l1C7LLMjArgp@sxjhkhBoQUUxRJghGrvj3CbfO4ViKhWnpW@0J6vivhPIo@oZWwLp8jqB3s18rlOl/m2XxG3Wbr4RbcVfjf34B6sGYf4jb7te4IJOBmP5vXmmglPiZ1XuPfkzf4x066@Hf0Gv/YyRv8O5rgH3vawb@T1/i328G/kxH@PXiNf0/f4N/zAf41v5LNqlVx84JQk1LL6tXmTCQUVWM79eZXJu68Yhl2w@y1/A8gZXNllow1v2LMusZ4UuGe/fhPvvutb8VrtbgUp8/K5FTHZWqyCtiHGnnx6v24EKuxTXVTzViZbkbtqB1wmCzjsswwM1R7oKi0VZYxWGaembPMyFF74DLgLwMuM9NnmQHL2BkbIkIouCbtzARdfXgM4K8PgFz4M3EXaEfNdBlkZKHQRl@kRPDgumw3hQaLM/GlAbqmrMoZuWC28Ds@DfHly6ay1dLKJSYjUcntxstmvCU2RbTtrpVzrDM3NpovRRiaMyInPvRhMc8DBbYaU5pNhaMJMEBYvLpqt/c/fdhuKzgMNZ86h4v/w8NR9PXW/9Gh8/TQGTnwf3h4CF3HqKfup4BB379fA4btP3Zi9epOs0JsP2D9MWV7p1nPSugupICba@iX@sBrARGe9Y2mED9PoO5xjupH9fPz6lmV3OfBKzja1UWEIBp3@E@4zmGIC9SRc7jOztFBb@g8/7wZurhD@fwcvD5noHeF/6DgRV//K/yb/239P33OkizRaCUTF1fbCbqS@JdMXlxdXPn3ejKR8F8S2/CHHvCOSS6u6uikSBfgaiSSreTVFfeDeyK5zQHWIZvtOqVdxINhIRZmSdnyW@K/7hOy9q9mvApyL9et8xnqRzGxyvTFvppmc5bJJKud4LMVuEqsX9LmhWSVvlm42WmorT/9Hfo0yU6SIuVz1aq6xfiLltOq1VzwVixVq6XgZTORKN@86pkdtQD6Ry6XTFar8LITgM3AK6RtsLcpVmNNuLfu3eOZlLTLywBmNldIZdQMpg5yykO2hqd3fYZ7cXBIX/UAVpOP4ed0OCtJZOibQPjdubhYEe/dS/jfs9/ZTd67p5Uzl5ehz3gMXuqSV7vdM912G/2zl5diW6R9MOU8vGdKl5dqppxS40nHTXyKHyyErBKSyj7S6pRrGdi4litCsF@A/PZ2IVevF3LgUyjFk7im3sDit6C8cTFeFWMXVAe1VOQcUKyid3R/EPRlHBTYxVWMGpTl8skEMNIkyIBXMfxzkefy4SafTwJmrkQeUy2XedQkyxUSpVTZ/6ttgFYOQg7/Q0ktm8ptFbfug8yLf95s1YU8uXph1NSr2oVRwVn1q2rX//QzWsYw7t3LlgFFpUy1KbTbD3dPdtvtmiiKKCjBDT2JuwtoMMSNN6jm@XKLY6RSvU/NrJbyDNqTx5HiMEKwEiBd0bbyagmRJJh9NHwDKBG4trTBNgSNnngTyhxzG@AJ6gxk3oOL9ViHDfBiA1TemMksupjFeDjdu90wksMvPzR8pbSk3wU@RngJfi/MchKFQfzZk929/ZO0ti2xmPZody@tHT9/EFPxNb94p@Asvh/t7z48fA4Jnj3Z3z3e//jgs/3nz8DfY@eLK2D6/n3xjLpWvJ@zz4VX7hvdMHRjahjt8@n0/DV7ZZptExrTmkKlnIHLPKMNdRnri3pV4dc1Pf3VK90d08Xe/fDb737437377e@@@@1vv/vt7//ky@9/G34/gt93@fO7/6acx/tPvvxnv/vut34bPP8D/P4Ifj/@yZe//k3@o/c/ht9/ivj9sf@LxOM/AWD98k@@/N7v/OTLX/kB/P6l//vBzd@v/nj17/u/sP6H6b73u7fH@e6/hd/vcVhB3O/@FvfD5434v8Xj/coP3v2Lf8f//9T/Q@dvv/sXf4w3/@Wf/uBP/9O7b/17TSv96b9@9wvfe/cL33r3C9959wv/WHv36/9azURvv/vu@3/wV3/4e3/1h/8j/f@I7r/3Pv/vfvBP/@J//Yv//S/@0P/9GH7/Dlw//ot/D13lb//gh/j/vT/42z/6If7/z//qb//g1/72l/8ncvwGd/w///Lf8Ptf/@p//Jvf/M5f/fibf/NrP/6b3/iDv/o/fuX/@vX/@Nf//e//9T/5Fnr@xo//6o9@@S@/9e2//IV//pff@nLN/du33r98D/8v/wF83r@c7wPnfer1oT5f/kzl@ftgY5EL0AlQ9y@9@/VfBAL/F4y9@/aP8EwZ/Nb8/0hTKc6P@Nv/BxzazTpjSAZc8Pu1d9/@LqLofwAUwX@Ir@@EL0sh/OU7ixdA62@uSPRLP/nyn/8OvcWMSp1WbXDsLmml1BboN1vlsj9@@ws6kOQXl6GFAPycvoMcainsO8jb3v3wm@9@5x@/@@FvvPvhL@PgLeXK6d20pN6xGgYR8@8RDyMW3iceRvwC80/RFJuU@gLe2Bd@4BdffCG0LxU8vHj/Eny/IC9@MR6Ehxv9oCAM/fG0I7tkUbfvzPjOTd83zJmxxsuXLVxvBT/MPUWyx1YgGuWzbJbyCzZjfFkH/SHSbIucM7yTLwbPBLwt/hfOmcBSM3@6F56phZMcfjo/C@4U8pBNahYuJpGsxrh0tMV9aJ2Y8s2VGdZgNkvNQAkGB@SQgqAHII7XailMWOPlgVdetHqJUVFSqRrUG1PzNOl2CUHMHhAUSFlLHbH2Vm3GE6YQXj1AR0pAryNR1cRUqfYQMqzNHjKEhcAJ7MuXtXqpNqsjuLccH6lZ6gGVCYHVUrP6W3ivEUxIJ8QevoWilGqpVL2EGWIlefOk27yR8lQ5qnuKpfw2gCdu99@5z9hHoloS@SLBBiKMx8Z7ahEbI0J0CG@mtvzq0H/gpN8WIXyDsvJzYTx8h2TTHS6uYgSAK0myLDP44fr7DrsPwTMOKkXZwiPFIaSIIogCQg@G80MpIUXtm6IXyD9W2/rgC4FhZTY3N4VYXcyKhzKhTlGYe1qhsw@4HRDViwoTC2URvQ06CBKUBdJXKf/NOC6sxRkHzD5K8d/9@1vsI6gmPRd@ApNSWSfnxDiU7VRK1AB@3UkJL0AtEYBOCdClIM9qtJCXEtJpxuRaDMPY4eGhXwjyeFETUkDmWlbFd1xOmk6nMUghy2k5nfafMj3JQ/YdMoX6T3kTkUtf9GaalquC9lRl6MWiqo4KKjB6vn37FlqF9ldVDkD5ZP5WKy1XokDw4DZcLGseHBjScmWBa@ZMLeQYS9AUK1xJlhRYgm0lBb4rnxciuBJxrVSKUzzAvpzYCnbeFVQiB5xejdWxoMHFVcJSPhkE7h2yvcOnT/c/PRm3Wkww6AvlRnvsOl3D8xIYtvvpQ34iQysXkrFGA0GfVDRkMMJ@JUPM@ODh0cFxhfFK@02QoIJVaV3Vr2ZZFWLj8efbMX/nkYgf2XPEY7xXFnVLaOUsJI3VhVjXQM0CF8xRAa6yqvDUGzxwZqDTp0UxrRZQs0vSpDITft6ZMjQBy@3FQJ/Ccxry9jZhQKhfSLR0gU5orYJQr/t79pgq1I/3TyDBySFTtYws1L9gMxkzlK6EulWzDHswGW7i5jexmREjddpsZNL4p2WzcFdzhbSaL7Y2NqwLCfNsUrNd4C7GK3i9kLAaX4WLCV8V2FfBCy7IA7cmMn9f6MFh1d@ch8bWEnyHnqjmoZslBZzH5uCEcfSqAnUvLwQJsY1vfGPC6nXQr6WDR0IMuMWQBfvTJLMnD2Vq5t7UNSh0wFjP/MzEryfKPdMbW/ocug5gI3Z1ddUHSAePmFbX6JWn6OH9qks@HXBfzXQhZlcqtbdqrihop5XK26ymCeAhbCm4AW4DCID2EWwp/K/qQSbZbEkBTqWKIjyy2ayAc8eCUDEERntF3mZqNYnTYDan0lYRAT/Ioc9qWnj5cWcfLeJmMzwuhkAAG0xclgnCijzMfysI9AZIw91x9Pnnqt85M/fuZXESI5vLhLMVVGN2BW2zmc1lEePC/3/hASy@mrM9rmcz6rYyBqcOzty2ooOzA878ttIBpwnO8rZignNaz6qZbWVaF5iwzc2tMrTmUhMnxgytO3M/se4ZVl/Gs0U1kTLQxG3ffHk9SFjv1XpOl77dXu3Jpm0bLp695glyObHq2GgIsIYmQei0OkskL4RB7ZxOiAtGbSCjbRnX1i2hJ3ec3lz2JnMLT@lYjluLgzgYDwIW0A2QQ3DuayebzVUarCWPnfGOoOWLqYaagQEEf2opraU3jJ1isdKTu5ahuzv5Sr6U7uEBIH@JayefqQzkL54@eTyZjI8MOhW0kytDArTGhnaTdkqVfL7VaIhiqkHZtPDL05w9SRsb0KcNvSfBExfAPEkrtSBxz3RrtXh8J6tqklrJZkpXwgJxiHOsYV3ApCmsWRrxfuFzgIrt2MBsKmk9bV4QFir9fv9q6yK1eBH0C4m/AX6uJD3duQhfq1IkXoVN05K5CAQfvQ/ovvDX9iqili@J1UZ18V4siNXWlXB/ZPRMHQ8DNTMXN1MVgClzqDHIqMmEq4rrOJNKx@g7rrGImFULQUReoJsRcuJVmF0zgzle3MyuEIk0u7gJJZcXr8JUQbGEqyvAO0c2oN23pVunTbMNtZxr7QMLAvLZDszsYrTYixdCbOvos2y9Dk19kStquXwur2ULhXxRg/GmnCvkS9DZMoVMXtMASq5cKhevgK4V5W2MvqLH9i4Ceq/QdwQSeoUbwmy0WPLtp6Z1UcpKvByJZPXqKvZWiH109JkGA@TaKwGD7meaVK9l82VwZdGlZaHATNA0SctKWVVSs/h/h0PD//ePr8G/hndIldWEE7SO8ykMmzDU2@wJWtmYOOzEwe8sDdgDo7smxt5Qpx3Ne67jeX@POA90@5QHPTS5Sdow6LGOH5vzRuZkuCbG8/EIDesY7j8YhP1RBwqI7JBHeAA313KcVRGK7PmzNbV8GhqBB2RwK/AQ/ejg48cnkefJ/u7eY6HAHhx@@vDaI@9HyrMn@49OwtciDw2S5kMQP7//5Mn1V/@RO3x@1J86Lv6ER4fPc4tb6IUHZoUcXMuRQm8C4t/wlQRLkChAEcsXA4cq4DGLe6Ac3/Od@cLCmUHn5/w0sOmF2/75wfCKcBIcEdYZctqOwbrcfhJq62Tb0Jfl1WJZEMbMds5ZMcN6jmXpLnP6/Q3wHOp43NFAgdaykBIx63PHtXrnZs/YEJ7iycqyil8px0IIjwHIaNoluxggzKCl3B5@0x6XpTrW1GDTMVvrCQ/0QqdrDoYwBp87QQSho@sMfh96QXojek1u95jwPMjvRoh1M7oAOl1JFPdE8bE@0etV16h6mUrl3j31mSuWxTEMybo3MPZnQLXsOfQi3Z2nxYks5h6x9gAXNixnjCqIN26AzF7WGq2dnFYvZfLZ0l//5o/@7k9@bVBTm5m9jLS98/RJvgK8DcRYRpKqL83KpNdo5VK@VM5qpXSpXMrl1UI@n1a1NKiExTJoBRm1pBZK@bKaLuXKIIbkyhCaLxd9WVgJhF9lqwJg7S5@NnubVCN5CDoQX4dkbxJ6ksX08H3KRAPSiAJqoRM6O75l1mAEZWqGZYsMIOqsy2KPHu1lHj0SxQf4gvs49jKi2MOXfCmTKT4QRYNC9kooUokOT1NCA4TihL9kMg8AyVMOAG33i@IQX/YLOJ8miia@7O0@eoT59PFFw/QQ7ZSH8BcreClCNBtfQEQnAK9DaBBtl@eTo4Lu4wtmiSGPeMgehInix0FxMOSIR@MAHgc13d0VxQP@sruLIXtU7Twv6NfwZZcuUXThBWhfFAfgGLjQ60SxA07sAaLYBVd3roMffqIczbvbE10U5xw9iCBRnFFsvXsqiu3AH7P5zC9NHrFboReV1/o@vZTxTxS1oNAYLRu@ZEUxF77koG6PH3@mDyc9Y8CvucufXajp48dZ3ZxN9x91Pv64Mxh03Pnu/sdHGLS39xjEkfnU7Qw6fsJOGy4HUu091vTT0fz6BbU@aLcrurUy6Gvtdk63rwW1520DSwipXkPJ/GuAGY3aexC097h9X1@1jkwA29j5R/Ds4PVgBM8HeocHBRcF0XPW6YhVJH9FaSYEVBhwBRi74ykwUzs90ruuU8X3WY1l0iizzBuFTKtKAWwEgn@meoXh/QTedZz8SV7MG7NaplWb1Yoa34jUT4jNmZY3xfTGaEct5ysb@o6q5VKzCpqvcPpxFpfUHZZQ7229YYlPkzsaKAFic2dHEhtqa0dTS5VC8cXWVBSTFbzvZIuVN4lMPMMY3pKNYmunmI@kKBZTuqJVikUQxQAnExjROzgn004kzg39NJnE0tIMAVSB6srmVE@z2k/M0rMaLxebJ6uzmlrlZo1Z5gawHtrQn3YnjstBDgDcbCdTwSX4hKiWSyIUQFESyWTI9EBhFxZ7QD//@snpyckXJPPV/cmLZ66B3Kvqv378eE8@OAze0Pq9/AhFUceV95BrLYVwmTTwOgElRH4MoygodIEfHhN0HUvep61zIM8GAYE9J9m3RCufPF6Cczx0znnOaGWhSuYM7a7B8OMAZo/ptTq49B5LUKmYnjyn8btdr9fatREZIoAqBqm@xshy/gLMgcfLHtp@oOQXeHTOD2jXMlfVTm0WmwGcdo1J6suR03uppbrVHn4T4EHtASautuHZqRo1w3UdVwR1Wqz2d@za1Pb0vvHMcNGqycHhJkgTeJ4u0WdGcpM19zH2HqoqV1LdZfaiZJ9ORwldqneSy144MRd6IHISXw8qfUFHPHGTxlW1X2OJFxD1Nby7myzRkx8kd3JVwNMD1k6CV@Zl/2WfaayQq5KqkUBY0JUIP1hvnSVr9a/Bg8M@rVSgNH5DnwJUzAwAmz0KgNhj86rarVksIbEZSxKSctVBrYHJL/G2LYliS5Ialy2hLkmfC3Xor9V5TK950w59ToZlOqqWKVRn4KcWc9UhNK/@YlZ1a@MpSAgWvPrzefw0q14FpALuAMyby8S7X/xmclvK17hflUBdWiB5tOV2bVa10UAlEEYtW4OAVCOXSYMSD7diGsZ8rZBWC@lsOpeWiugLA346nwZPUHJAwEhYCZExMZ2ZZWQ1rRpqOpF5afZeJtOnCZBbCGksmZ44@/Z0xMAHmgppk17hCehJaVsWKF89h@nbEhErsIwqVgywPmRjMz1EUEeGblGKZFJi2a2EtZnAOJsn0/F@o1Wp7M/GX4eghPR6p5AqZlJvkslqYiNZ84zXQr0q1JG9UK3HG0C5/lQn86ajBrQyuNSiVmk0OljFYiadzWShdmb7crAt1sVWOrNRUKGJrhixDcb5RnT2DyWehd@4jcK3ZUDTqWWtKsg0FZctaVJZyW/lM3w6kKcUxj57Q0yyRFMMTm4n4vGiFo8n41VciNgQ/Zln4GnEz@LAXeP31B0RhDGxIpY1jLBgjXQ4NxOUDsSxKwGlQpYD3fZCuLq42q4LXxGO8cjltvYC/4ovnu4e4t9XwKsMr6UXT58fPj98JDCF9nrK7Vh1oypX21V4keT6fSFWYQw4adM3K6VsMPahu0hT2/UX/NnE4wMAVyCj0w3Wot1dhomKG/sMTRbssDjUQXdHDU3LthpaEcY@4KZBVE1Tq7hME8MDCnIdGsO7gPJtp@p42u9rbD7XU1Kg7d9jbJDaFAg9setTAbu13cHRbrBBbXdv9YTB5ljBOerVgXWQh05PVf/YTjHTFqsx1hbz/vm4xdGenLjdFEQRt8TFLuKx@BX8xeIBmBdvgoM/BbF6milvLx0LKgfHgopaW3zBvOopms3cFmL36fCjxg8/slh4/BHXdv1lmWyuwJLlYNXkK/H7sXg8jssTFea9jcVW1ei0Ksaz6XgxHVfT7H68WMhSXapvxFxYLb9kpbb4pvqCSkw0GJxM@9pLDcg/ZjuBByiAODkHw3M@j8sBMeXl2PuGVso@PTi0H7qPIqekXtRj@OVwCQ98VSsv2hunKpB9VsyepmPsfowOCYhlKInGPQDhp0yFUgDi42oFiifEmhuXGw4u9LBw@@Fb@5OvMzaOZ3OA9WYtNqvl/H3tar0uqdsa2p0rsgqMZn21IGUu67y/1imgoEHIu1/8QW62XYJ3LaPCu6blU1q9rm5pLBkbv/vy99GE0MX@Z7tPWByXB/7uT35HK/7dn/wr2kEXv6IlAy1bjEFMdKqFYuziYnxxcQUXD8vHWjFeqFwxCW6@fKXG6oqqZW3brrKKoutbxVROu29XFT@uWlSTMU@K@ZtGs4W8lEioCpRqK1vKJCHs0o@pZUrwFiyc8ehiAVoEKrB/ZOY19f72DtRvJ5vTqhtAW2p4sJaFf9uGV0YF9unLS8bgpVvvDQamRi5FYZW3Ett@K22zt7hs9VbaYC9rddz@oOJx3GBZZwuPJ@LSZryeUrbiDLQ/Vm9cVa9aKVoXAjX5hWFs2c1r5NncwPMpy15bNvwZWx79YaLAw4PX4M3YeuWJia2kovR64k2y3zZYvg4Es6UsDg2zrWC1h/9JUjP57hd/XdMKf/cnv3rZvmx/oYEGXS4XVC32059uT@2pZ/TqPwUAt5iPCbRgEoTRzgs6Qu2ZcYucpp8qdMhdUNynNmoKPH6gS6P2zEDKMge20SNdWjhDyZAat80tGPYSFG0LrUukSdMgi2HJqiAEIjnXJNxBN00w2BaakW20ksKF8FUMAsGDgTZSFb66AAUeIxA1nG7bs6bumM73JCid2kqze5AEcvgqGofcIKsY/qglAftWtm4m5UX2CGskRbKR4XloahIGXOGrkMS3tW3N2VhHAy4Y07RhmJQxCpWTAnoNyLsFeVs8QZt8E1R7HiHNeOl4Ihu0DeGrIDgRFkyQp5i5DRGqwKi@CgiAOiR8wGaLbbNskl2YqVR1YcfyCk8ioKVNPTAeIWAyhNZDYyVB4irGAy/QcvDrrkgXfguDOBvxDIBwGHzjQg30JExObyiiknWX9wYFsMiSWoKqxu7dW5SqVjN7SUY1Qvin5hin@agd7NVlBWCBjvlRryKmGVoIrQa@IdkBxlNUXKA6iZsGrUaSMhFfrwQB/t@baJEirzUVBVSxAn578V7RBZRBYkQ7b8Mu264xVSsmWVj4LpS9S4WiI/yh4tycfSRrXwSBV1DCn8aCbycB0zqJTp36dHvdeggDtWKKH65BG3KcGfhWP7iVOGR@B5MgdZgKqmJaFLtvuqDS0Y6KwEBlIqsmMdnCoCeVg/i4lmO4ZT@fxAelwtgMnjoaWvTz2SADUV0HGtQbOzZZZiTLUXheAigCeJRv1I4Xe2qf44fO/LahxNESeWTQDikfS0yWJukL8ZQWtzR0XFD9A9ykmTGQWXfUY1qZJYjQyPieHYJLUiIqcAc0A8RxxzJGUKRjw6BDdl5FUQYgLU47ZIHwqQl0NXxkwghke8pDjmDl3Dw1lRO0OCw5fTyLx@25xFDAxO7Hd0/41v4sxzlllnlq8BnxxJI1HI@BbgTifRowu/gBYiu4LUfLpnGKBuQkigW/IjyK3FlKR9JuJObJm8@supFoY4te0nhjQqtYxpluR/BL16XgTwp4cy@wp0VWoeBdDlmu4VvSqcXRRkZoIkrwLYPVyCiVjCst44QYEwOLWugUxq5xxlC9F3CMAabZDWzTYC@G2n6VBgDqe9Cz0NDmxK2gRSUoidtLdKHr@QzeZh@xrCZgRG7uzDdNBjCw6WvL0CEMkmI9vEkPGkam5QXkK9A7Rz0IQ1sePvlh@oC60U1GUBfkzTZ8cDjoUF41xrtF8JKPvGDvQHqmqm9AYAFKuKIkGwkxBWBTYlLkoMP015NzaheIl1TYTUhphhB8VAMUEhV0ZDloSTHyRTIBAh7oHv9shW@G8/z8XCbbsFPXlA0Pv9LlObZuKeOBCTK2o0yM0dj/HrLZVcYB3IVL4h/nk8fD8c4Mpdta@d6cPwWh79X8zU2JeN@L4@B4hh@hGozIjhwacPOIoB6Z9AG7bsLfa8XpT2ulLwL6qyD9SaX4FQJhDMHM0vN0Nw3A0p3uabp/3qv6AWfUIQE4tKIReKLFZjd4GXmByxz3wxjOBPloGNSxTmm9GiCJfC57kTWvYRBzHrz672NzBols45ztuq4@T1B4EmMjASfmJPawOQz7FAJONOl9wc0Hm7PGvLWUfBYmh0Et3K3hopE44eJ2oNyWNIbPePgMwmc8fLbINMi2MWtxkQy9rrA6SPVoWzSIiWDmQZwrbnd5EUKQQR4H3Yn8MOZ8ye8Kft0apQ7wzd@gHWsBYQBNjAHhRkJpvGg2mi3bM863WillAMQuEiKgxQF0o0U4Pe@FbsS@dWaNHW/Jy0aTsjAq@eVGr@7QpwZOK1jHsIGIMDi@TLQCOhj520q4QOBXGCCgHAaBKBrsThJmshraLqdAIJyGuMAxL1jDL0yLpC8/yPcDcYmjniM2CqgVAYT@YZWgmBDCgp7Dv8kYcIfPXQfiBHEl@ozcCK3RxVtxwOS1rsJ5TZUaKVIqSQqKCWhHcbV2vSpBODRF41pQpJpXfvtHi7/xwcXvQ79YXXoiWD5gVIVoV8GdnCBC@N2FsMrqtUi7QgmULd0yXBi59rl86o/WkM2WEqgZPB@sgnduTrrDRKTxu0nePnReVLTFSkgK81oNqjiv8W7J@0WAUo7wMJnnJ5sHhOCn5wwEYGRWJjP8ZLNoslmtxhkHm61Jdh4p5IwKOeNJeOzZmkK2/GSgPR0Ewws2TwukU9xqKgI8lQ@jIAaNRebpZwYu/r9CS5m4fuLnueA5RAU@DaGIjXTWba3MvREpdIRpXQOAhHgDQI9/3rkiXGd4qhS@hTyKozLgUfzNJwPOK4DAiAVXuTXpREhkpAODwC@maByAviumGoKo0hw4/mX4T0wHnsFPvemZWY6pLntm0tf@/kE8W4jZSAeNSB9qJocMGTWZ57ZvhjUqc8TY7hQUHJDqOucOS6wQtsFfmfpJlY7ldJSRjpt48KOv3Fcez5OB/oCrSOz@2JnoEyeXq3ClySSyW5U/1xnMge3gt6IiFuVB1us5hmfHJ9CoXWdgm56RZmjs89Tw1Q7D/8SFEJWTfafjCYK/nYyrsQia0xWKuu02foa@3U7gLs1kJdxyTps2kTzjcQH1X3BF0gN78oEejhNO55XRnSTvhomfR/CTnZjd08Th2A/EOdldBjysC/I/hA5BgmGes9AcyfQ6itKdSYI@6zF0Rs4ApL6pJwuY@hr4gwVsLJA@HlNZ0kxHlbYS@UgG9ZJEN60n/aRf@@Ck7GtaQk@G6bVlAEvISDP3Oo4Rs@6K7Nprs@PJgvyOP7y8x9HyHt9eXtLCr5eZq@Y1HvhhWWcTCwgQcVGM7N3FwKoD3@rdKM5SUUJvlKt4gvcuYo82yfWwpLsQddePLveBPtLhmwdvYcE/W4f/2xswSL7/vs2nQ7dnx3PgNyPcb5qgz/t5wWJwAqIfJJH33MwuJO2H75kXxMUvqz5CEQLEWGJcNlqNho45BrXbCyeQA8B30DzuS7tB97RZrcYDV5TJPUuzU219Ez1s9wxLnxu9hB8zHYEb1PgIFDbiV@9XcWR0xPQcruslYOxKhqEwjCPSeaTKGpLR02fJ5Hqy4lHMkHpoppxKeLAefxh@gzXjFF@Nz1aDHhCPx3A69szE6c/xfDznHyaw@LfdfD7Kxx/ekmjz4m6EAB746KmmF9kmb2OfR4mwSu8xIoRx5eUqo93wACKakrrZhh@GortrCo0bSVQLWllY/iTP6hY3b2vxCFUENMkXo96PJO8iuvemuQipcWALFrb3YUPIDci4g6Xb/X@7@9q1NpIlzd/UVaQl3KhMqSRhg7GwsAUIW@dg8PBhtxfT6kIqgdpCUqvEh9p2PzPzY29g5/9cwt7K3MP82qs4G29EZlWWJDDuPrtnnjnPaVOqyoyMjIyMjMyMj5wNUd7cOWL93pRMwDs@p@vdsqo0ZgjUuCZLulGHt9usX7gOdsZ1@osDp3f0FwDPwlFDGMr0DWdaOl2q4i8XwcDSWvQbUtIJikVFIblGwyrlmGcq/vlr3Gbz1jabU202U23GMyDdpFXIaaaa1KOA4blrCLphe3SLdMYn7J3pz11im/7X6wdDnFZ8XugslDueWrhaKJNAXggXyrUcCeWF1kJ5ix@ihfIBP3xaKP@VHpK5tfBloWymBQoM6Sc/vMR7LcLxu7lQ3sy5X51R8CmMTLv@QjkeUyrzQn4yRYgU6Ddpjbhi6/V1N0fDkBY2Vio9BY6JPGyf@BzG4/@K9H9JssXpd/ARZ5yPuLBaVKXUomGtGNIOLRsmvcOMmVzWq3ltb5stwOIiaGaR9nh2HQZPanh2IS2MBDF85RsN@ksIQm6WZ2OkrJXsnujo1olDeZDT7TP1fNYHWjn@fkyFT5JGOLOarm/GKw1CBvB@eKLybXhOoWOaY4xwJ@vOQAtE/Xnhjk5hrNO46NG3R4jPutOFCNu8KSKjxGAtmU46HF/OobFBf5BmEv4KV4OOXYcP5WRSgnsnqrFU0DPzls/8WvcMgsGe/O5d3bHqAbWUCMLH4@KJzLJ4XWBZjE@JrLM0VZl8hIIlc2iGh81PnLVuSz9yORE3Hq8Vty1Dpq40yZIrLSapso8YXpfBSFqPN681RPb6vu2rqXmDs5YcAFg141ZEvva/Q3/vi/5uFGpDhIkGZinWs5fSafX6zlV2AvNu0uz0AOKjp7bcmcpR3EJCctodWJr5Xbw2peLD5EOUfGk0hj6h7RuyxXuCb9Btcm8hsKAlDK/SLz8t0ctPS7cTaloj6V75Rmnx0ZKGIx2PMU26djeu0vFZQ4wvfL4ddL97gIfpAbYHD/C4A8MJksssH1722MolmdsktuUNRGqprESQ83VpPMzJSxL3fHUbX9vSi73G/tbe7s4HWnSfPn3q6jV6nOCHWYuz1ngdF8hsTh6vBzO2LUseUkvhshvH8dF5fzh68LGXmZIlIqxJGQioFcN@eo67WpZZ8nxi7lI9KWtRVMP6lEyDICWVoOoEWLI7mq4jIkg4yj0KNBCj3hK9Pd6tuZxEqdHoBRdho8HLl0n1rFcxDI25EXf/ln1QuIyGnNJYMoBdOw4H01Bbe@r96@qhOnxdU9tHm39VH/aO1Pvq7iHiKLw92tipbyr6r7Z7UFNOykYS2RKxoSS6boXNEClw1VKx@EQx5M3@YCxyJ7fpyvuD4EK97jdDXFM9j4KLl@fyw@@Fo3WpVaPt6BhnmB3OjnnRGcHegtM50jYWyk2L3SPh/6Co7CntaS@w573otzrtDpV1sPcddMLIeNSpbodGkOStcSr3RElC5kY2HeKMrLDAuqbqAZXH3Q2BCcT@CiRGCUn12PKVJlz8v@@m4GFt/82BQkiOzb3drfphfW/3QG3v7dPPtx/qu6@InvWDw/36xhE@ccE3e1v17fpmlV8IAkVfIVbGL5fR6E4UfBRnqjQ/4ebbH9Dwx7/Sp97Q4NV1wI6ikVq47EH6dIJu57ewtbDmXEZQX@CcylcFKjdf3X/1jtZ8Ff6KG05zFcz2B5mjiLOJzhfVc26NJss6zbc1PV1p2cuXXL6PuBgrJBQK1ziGRo6fPWWAsxFPqxOqzCZsVHD2LaE2eC4b0NTQA4INUMZgpaI4EdjCgvecQa5Ta81uH3FRpTUxItQ/UPWlMTVZc5hi2lYGQOHhUe/hPKi0Fr8gvqcXS7rZ0VAKqMfxCymgnsgLqKJ12I6oZV3icrR3CfGsVuTFLxeDbb4WVk/jFxsB72JXNU4ybjykgYoTKSLwSJfTvckpD6ek5TzwXCXi8kiF1u3KxAglCSfJRLlKZNs2KpkhYdPGVYM2e5Pc1vhK3AA7oaA9ilSu4vrqEMZBYa8jifbOukFPTKAS0x3mPbWKGE8V7YfeiRPUsc/MoM8MiOSYaTzieltaKwzvW49qbky1GGgbSU4Sa0zQvoXAxhQCfwQMAcqndjpNXqnYdxdg@m3NyrmoTxyJc9vf7fLEzq3LZpiqoK22cr90fvvN1UT2UvskY6fI2NEQ/RYOSa3kq8x2f0hznMUqp/SCFGye9wejjoxhLt0DvnHiZY5KY2Gj1n6urKdaAx0mW@z1e1ajp8TFt7R6Skx5n1aZ4@XuPBZfSa5n4nxahMXuDugEp/2r0Lo783CJdB3i@IUUYb4rx@HneMSYiP7pJLLjd4UUsauV9a2Nj/nff/aQJ1bEgqRpNkaH@I8YE23R9OB7PjZYHELv0jPN5PeLLk9RW9vgaWmJWW6A0T7wvEP7upeNtfibmBtPv4c/0eR7fvnlS0Vq5SGZdG7v6DyXSDdPHZsmPa5zorQJiCU7CVmS9TnzxmOYsbx@CR8ijAKCFvUgR7Bvn8iep0WI6d3pZZski05irIc7hu@qdbaoSDLAwzfIHo/CT7mNyuK6W0gMSpRFzpwR0Z6BXHJdyyyF16spcFt3gyP5fX9wq3diJ8vDd0HbuhPad@GWX7wdlixLFqz7g/39DrCyuP0hsNR373bAskhOQ4s5PWZObz4bW9Pe3eLPU2PHc4/AYO3FCUoM1GrtssdX1CbKeE4quDaYRCE6ONyq7e@rjOxPqC7JPWwZWloMAvYD9Taxtu30WNj5sdIUb5Zj5cm8SVm0Jd5at0/mmcS7RVRoHcTT9IiFRRLLvN25EamnVxZWIdj6ngWioVwau89GBkXHGvBX2gMSssmgWR10ZnYzK4tPJ7KNwDXdPNGNbRt@trCWtRupgYdjG5BtExScwbNk9vi9F/24bNoRBQuRntDhFmnStN7QPuGAGh5QQd9Pj@Adw2KGFEb2omBnDe1g@FVMa9h/nqGYkUQJF13YEutaOdaoiX48b9QcNkjEMhDA0lN/FItm@mBEPL95bg@omyx6ufQSREomksW@tLmCqp981UsYUyNeJyuxQm7PtXnG5thgeYLTWQ177fZCD2ELvTIpHiabIml7Z1P5v09TskqkWjI0n9kZ85EgrywvP/4W7MlemOr5Pwtb1pBJ@Tm6GND@PgEZjSM@3ifOre965nvCAHeQTkzrzYSZqEiqzow1JdV3Xoxs/AgXORciZBCaH/l3J1t11c0EbrOhy4pkQ@ciU32wpnDcUZk1U9T/endzEMjfbO/B97cnkw2FYDr4FVb5b/rDKEy88qygNtYrBANIvwuHwx4XE3@mC0DJsRvTnc527G0nBq/SK3zk@za7J23tnSRmt545a@BG@HjRR8ptnO6tTR7v5Utrdle36zs19YhDdbZTZ5GZYca1ZM@DTu8uBFgG87kElg/24XsYlek/wsEzIIlM7M2XY9q438SNKUJa8zHnbtJmoVq2liZHvx01gx7CoHiZh5HKeD9QRT6Fre1tu7NO1otrqfqEXDTo5aiWl8n7Ga5K73CgC0hpEDKaeG8tWPDUMJaScK8568M@Chdb4Y2cnrHlZFAorRZXnjncu5438i6On514j5qVjKLFN@hdRJfD69ans/75VVt11eCX05vm@LdflVp@oh5TW0s/SLzk0kqlwCFqn9K/q@pZkTlXI/iCYz8jBbQvuXGVWlDJPnztgXL5gTfNZXhITHCpenRhuBAudqPKxfHKSaVXKa5dHPdO1uDkN1qsjBZLizm8@IFWUZIxcjN/PDrBmmqfuoa9K4WopJyDVbuGKHYNoTdvgmGnv1PdfZU6jYMCgCMwbevNB@qSbnsO1mzwPfF74XVOH5N5ChzrQEFy5tgrqARffz5PxnFMq0OY0ah4pM1GN/zv2HXmiv7lYNTnLyYGJVhLfel8ceaMG1ORTxSoyHHHRKqEfwHBScrkcDEkb8diRZ0vibpWgu@ka4E4Rk0Wh5mPmQx8CoGo9uU6PnEiPwya50AC@eW/cDX1/DlnmydWi3w@xYMpRzBkh4niCR5xAUJ/BnzbgCZYc4/Y7cOh7uN3CQ/yhs@oRuwnwwbyDmuK@ALzb/WZ/Zu4/nMigBB@TnQuXx9xas2LFEnxHeTDBQR4S2/8cc0At0oZlDl0FrClvUoCnC3FmUZoVpOJ3s9dg5xCK/qf7kG@xL@muhGXd6U4k4TvqfWvCLTkIeVP6/jTTarlrGp5U80Utkgx901q4KSLtkdvQppWY7UZdruEtNBiLiEHHtm/V7e/GLcfHaPNkxh5@Z6f@p5PfffluyCVlPJpgU8Kle1CmeznpNxXlUmKeVNtVRQrLz6NdNMnlSQpu3ZX2cgf9RudpPB6PJTClfGH56kPeevLTzNGX748SNWJGTz@fizfNX8v6ZGPsUyVfZluH38dPUAhG89qW5MJLvV7ne4LR6cm11/AZhmiplJSnVNOKjOpKtoHU4sT0uBwzs/Tdr2SQFksGYnDcyaz/vxlxtdKxovcJBrixTg1sWbMEYtK3OYiE@6GHRapHf78wALBMMFoyszcdVN5rCuPLbAo9cA0K16QUxOcujY5xSvwi/yCf8xkTyNnymVnf5wTzG@k8@LdnCYQC90HmdlkSksTuIvIS92pO1aRpO3xJMTZQmLXOgWO2wzFB7uNY/AHsZywBYWRFFN0j79oSicFSoZ9bxtCfPzq/K3wyHkVkI496IY3qoptRsBeWE7KwX0URqMIgbA4Rk90ORh0cevICt81u1DrFABLy7huSSBaK7vv1GHZI@U9PGmHdKrkqz1AvoaBSPIhujw7gzMZPGD71xCtOHHpjHyn2hvLgQbNmcdL4mYeKgTfYAHc7ZzZSMjIyewBpaNB0Ax9h3S0iLQfR7ra7uhErXyeDr8RxFujJa3sOP902Wl@2nyF@9ynpeLjkkWyK30dXPQfP0kcrIhI5sMSQiYul544jnU33JS74TwAemoHC/074s3wKuz1QqdKKwYXjEhpjcLhVdjyHWc/jC@BAResjJtJ@GH3L4dNOdwhpSsgZoSXcOTJdRhxGP5ifZbr4ibflXkOLq2S22Ya6qtOCwQ0HiftPm6H@cICYQKEHqh0EY6IKI9clUaJ7541Lqy7XOAgiqiBOCfW3URMhl5/1GnSyPBJltMlUHINkjTWa01gQu01uwGcg/1ZCMA9JqGAQcBcJd2Fg6Mvzb8LB6U7Zu7YAzMyBZJ@fZ4rNN3DYYekb0JgHhWuZuFOA3z4un6gDva2D99X92uKnt/u772rb9W21MYHvuPGRTlHH1av93ZIusS36XJrvkcvMtUDqpnhD05194Oq/fh2v3ZwoPb2Vf3N2506QSPw@9Xdw3rtwFP13c2doy2@fScIanfvUO3U39QPqdjhnsetmmpOUk/tbas3tf3N1/SzulHfqR9@4Ba364e7aAy3@lX1trp/WN882qnuq7dH@2/3DmoKHXO26gebO9X6m9qWT@1Tm6r2rrZ7qA5eV3d2Jjq69363tq/YSMDq5UaNsKxu0BYWLXE/t@r7tc1DdCh52iTiEYI7njp4W9us46H2Y426U93/4GmgB7V/OqJC9FFtVd9UX1HnnNw3qELjsnm0X0MEJVDi4Gjj4LB@eHRYU6/29raY1ge1/Xf1zdrBmnJ29g6YYEcHNU8hjSQ3TTCIWvSdnjeODupMt/ruIa0ZR29h7@DSIL8nwhCWVaq6xQSGGQR6S0Ta2/8AqKADD4Cn3r@u0ft90JSpVQUVYFGxeWgXowaJiId2N9Vu7dVO/VVtd7OGz3sA875@UHNpwOoHKFCHQcYHYh1q9Ih7jXEivOSRmNUxnOvxcKr6tqpuvasDc12aOOCgrrmFybb5WtPcR3Bi6xCl08eZQXBhH6y0p19dhQjHOX0iM/uMJo6YtLm3VaMVWQe7yiQfjmjVWZ0IpWR/o5Um/kg/UyFrWuHp5Vmj02v34WMaV5ODj4vozENyJBeZZT46d@QI0@crXCGbbTTeVRu00T1oNFzvPjVTaHyrhj4Gv6uUq/uIzBPYeePgp1wWuj9PEWr9B33RyYZ6uIBASaH@D2L6FlyErioUWqGuBud9ADZHR5Fcm5zjKoVEIzs7IiVO0iSfTPDvjmYHrpgz4P1mA@eksIzkQv2I/ul9SX7I4mC9IOksx12FAjaxjEbnt9A0I41wSAT@R0ck6LS5ST8Kw09nuaLdHPb8/lm/38q5rqnDZUe0DzzLud@ofhqeTVTPT9ZnZPnaWSdtiMy@m1WY@P5Zk0zpcfGH3LMc/mmM@I9rsJGYDzg15ab4sFofWuZ@kOqwSPKUDm0B9woeZOh8b6o/1t9jN1dcerI28f51/F7mFuwFEbiXFrxjrnfCf16fSAGaYByLg0jS0REyCgWrjrE3iQtfU8FzFLrutGD5Q2v1ecjrOpGEFNnLoGu3idV42LmxsSc5/Gq/@mbjaHubRCewfbK6/HRlzYnDbv3oyd8PaIdj63LUsQGt46Sn8SdrlmyS4sMzxQptnrA/M3ChgIKIWm8GjV8izkNst5G2ZIIgQ3cj5IfqwUQvE4IOGcUBOB44hl9nzkzNALlUV1305iK4YRU/IF2JeUAbs3THPGo3@Aew4@lvpnjcIc1AmsU42jBxLu0uWO5lto2pKG9uOHAPivgZw8cSxi2mAR91sf0svGv5l@ZtaxQjMWXEfOVh55qExINJLJSxq@jJzH7LcUb0ATBHD6M3P2p@o8cPOsAdh7sLolF1dEBk3I5r4pw6OYzWnT7WkE@QRQRB1UxLzxVO@V2NFM89fZwcBwaxZgOjgpQ4sPFNA16L44hMNskWsC8XXPVZOBXBOwBnTXOs/k2cO6s7GsqaiR@if5uoFEpgxUFOhGrXcRuOKfIhjmNhyJki05@iB8P/B9JkBvzntOMk6Am1rCCA96IkQxVa0faVidK5NhcN1u1GQk371YcEzFd7YM7jjunbmxvxryES6NEZmxcfOOxhOzeDAGByHGzY8zc2STsPaOv0MuPq6rgn6TUvBjml1wqzVEzBza@ceKx2eeZuBT9c5cpZk9XgDlVVL2XjdsqznrZME1t59TDKCDjXxP8oPOIDkHjCM5eei9XqJGcV9SwzckCHWrIWnFYcMYnU0q@33to9UlaIzJTs1zdfhlAEeh34TPeT06n0lZjnpiMu8kqsDjkKHiKoY5uMxUeHrDtlQ8xuCDgPW3wYgowro2ssEF2BzqH6Emgq95ANRdBIYnWYxBmEuHV9Ii0vq9cx9nwyCQ6NsT/qSfD@UE61TAlfAnxoDG13eV@9CcaEcvd@3RYWKzw66HuwXURjciyh6yO7TLPfH5LqGKDfhKPXGbu@eq8PHcJedDnU8QtpPesM9YmEUfqpGahNsnvnZUai5jNqUWcEb4WWz/zBXboIYSEq4Ulu8isqR8xreHTdHDp2bhZLKvc8@fKcaMJhSZmIz9WK@vJFSglBdcjQkCnYieLNBdtscju4d4in33V/@AlrP1SgXitsxZFJLZB8FiiDVO9xjMfmSLo@6Ed8okFDgROQmBIlOUiLDVVpjX6q2UnbNWWS6JiIXco9@f52YiY11lLUUMK4unVivpU8DSaotKRDg8bBQktLy4zKrA3X11s3YxwtNH1trTIfe7FIKYsSUXloVEc8idyMnz7gSR/yVx5GmD30BnfcWgUFwtBZca86LecYP9gUvO@Ew5Z9JkqaTCsY4PiNtz79HvOiOTrUYf@awSgKx7QDaBY6NwWG0cj9pX/ea2z2u8FZp98JaJ@GkPc3IvHwOOZHDNjZsH8dceIk/tCyCrXGybPEl5EwbPgd30uuWaG5olE4yNlmCqPhuHouYSL45BxGgEnSVubvwWSMtLjOk@WkkpP2P2V7vJK7dmvdx6VZleVGHwC0gFufsKAQH9IROyZZzqdrUwVO7ypg4Xiq8ipwb7HYS2H8jEjE1zApjA0yU2YJdiewM7sV4@PWjdfiGIRDBFoKt0LkAIpy/NoLkAebpMgLWAqUVWm1aFWVW5QbxCHEw/h2ci89/QdjTwj8CfRLj2dxyyxGYBHXNtGWItmv6CijhAubB3ZYRrMkJinWOev0LPdDTrhxMwk1/Xl8GzXY8oeUIh1mb4orMSNztPFBfr9cg0ROY@xiUVlQCy7H7YAKUh3lirczbPgt@1me/LjElZMzCKZNDTlnIX0bqZpEJWQanjCvtVGWmMrfnjFLS/cdtQkCVmaZnFkZr3MZo7mwB0pH1ldca/WHJIwzE9TTph4L0ag/WLgn9W6VHTMjs82iddN1v2kILMxWocXyUYtJWxnjcbzmTOIzwTRpirGlGfEQtq/8HLP5JBFvKg3Mt0pj/A063EazxG4qXlTi8W7J3MeieAWLXrPQxFOKcUeQ0rX4/XGDOt64XYJomLK9arDEaEBkNMbyaIGaIFNMpftTiLlP4z5BjxZRDu22iHb2@NxK1EkjORPy1HxKBbkEPRG4HU6bJJcGbRhfIEycaLixkIoVzhtvzFd5pfwpggzjgwCEVhzmk3MoOcFNBmuCjzg7QDvXgLVQCZKIntZtC4c46H9MMI7Krw93tMVDY5wvnawJpJsYEu0quNRdkIy/Of08btwwlClS0BSfQYq4R1Oy6fz@vfqzfaFyBEFq82dt6Vv00BlXLRI29I/9qXEDHThpStdMzaj0RGiwaKC5QLuUs24o21Vof52hcDysG/Q0og2EvM7hz6KugXDeK8WY2qhy0xqjiKvJLbPNVfl1qZIwlPwG@fVUFFWXN64EIBSMqX6lRBAQ1pSxx6UAh96xOS@FqB4jqlgpYVrSS46Kmth5zvgOouoCT5atEsVZJZ7ZMPIzgZBiMbtMggjpLLOLJFBooZuJi1Xi6ez@JCVIITa8LxSnodCjkqZhPHJCQE6xXXQTiXJcUl5RczB/fLLspj7G/M1fnxWtr8XJr0SfGMPjfGny62ox9TXV7NJSumqqJtHDtVtNfSRSuDbCsVT4c/9j1xQ75HlsE2ptMlJahrbPRgp02mXSvs3/JVLP2Snb6BgGnu0ZbrZfDUmxkgrKfncAdrXAVwaI3f6ne2ssUw0mOlcAx6Uzzi452RCyxprBUo9uYadrIu3FAQrMnrbfVu8Ot7dTYV9Px8bQ6CIcLheLRTDxqR383thW4yip0y@kSxfal91uYXD9l@G70wLL/jDklABls4MOaUhoUkR@f3gmmSGAAxVF6bx2ZMVe/7LdtlMw4IYSg0fDJiV1NATFC1AnNnp5d8gHQAxSL7A/o4Po388qnn3XgSiaGoq5hqLaMAm@ypjbMyIPXrRhnx3fVDEwCGZjzUTrlltZ/4wVBJlNeLA4fLH7OTFPzrwOu92@p94j9TIiBcx9naywvW1XKEoR3DCyd@9lxPFoPRVedbqWXzGK2LwOcGZhMnkmTFx4xMbfD89qN4Nc5vinDC0r1OVFdHMR8ak9lTnLuDpY/D3ACh8S2vcqfREMck2m02RhWur1DE6eCKPHJW/m3idVxOUzMU2zb5cGUWej63OwBuq6y7qAiWXPw8s9uaV4TNzMx5tSGzQsCgyNE2Ku3K8GXM3@cWLxatRu308qchoAGdjvkoiSCeXPCUS@A@AZqKcf0RNRtP@ap2m9PRFQRBQcJOuYljuo0EAFx3nYrPx6natWq2p@sLioqtUNesjnVXWjqrbwYmNDbdHvDfz@obK0vLwmMnfL/UwvN8zLr2qDYPAJ52LzfLhFP@lbBX5jsNbGEM8XKvPe2nyj8nx9LSocVzfg1k9P//kv//M///V/Far6x7/jxwb/OP4pLuT7fmG@@Xn@h69r@H28dbIwf3o8PzhZOFsDl/2No4b366N8kJiP@sNTJyurgPWW7UjNPpujz@iqymQJvAiGn0i6lFW2GRWy@m0kmaNYxmabofU@hB/lKW3hTdKBya08IZEloGMcx9PoNEMY4NF6Q5QkXGAHKvXlbsUc3CMcTFwgvlXJ6kg8rLNehfBpSSIpwBeXVqx8pxeFPZyAX7HOK91znID@dkYNzb@Fn95EZxv9G/XoY049KqpHnnqUyfCf0sozeuvOFzrwzpVitB3IZDz6klwtwMxQRR1W9Hj/wLl2JsjtOPOcsgeQTJgKLixecF68@2NnGUm4Fp05c0g7quSIhC@ZUCX7eb73lYblM5X4mkm52rCi0NC7GG7MulGJxxcqUBCJIUDS8oUQpNynJnHTxx7JeCqYN3qsHc4mxIBB1v1X2zzv8YLWovmetnlO7aWQ5ojN5@Ut1sY1cYZmtPFF2k8Q4AsV2U4W2ZNwIbvgiJW31Uvupnhh2/3TzCe2DuNwZGzTpdLvymICsea2CTff034t2pBbrldUphNfr1hNZSZtv5VjVbm47I46A@2uwK1jQn2OW/sqMwkjyoAEjsTsL0/PMD4oMJGiJoZFkmWNVauPrstM6GnXdBpg15ebI4sIhZ9yNLe/TMxtt8BeIoYdhAcYqdiUrx10upGOujJkYp8Fw1NkBwzanFBtJPdmfJ6H9LETGPfbMdI@Q2aT82Q@U1eyg2FwdhF4KrvbPxwG4zotW6T5jJq@Sz1ECCYggcmnm57VPYOw9EgPCVMk7gpbDiF5QXes06PJ2GZinxMMqZkKOuwKJkGKnZiS4ZfUWE3QMeHq7xgEG@Up4R3fRmoRy5IXlkYaUsZ2m@FpNjV1HNOCPXfiiZNxBNV4Zhpe0JUusdBe8MUvSfIuYgTotjPaC1C7Iqw8Q/tYnc7CXpBanAZdxzj6F9aUrIuYz5yKUqyRHA3laSnJeAesSI/8KR0FQtYmE87Imcvl5j5GOp1b1l5HOMh3bItfCFQnTkDHCczYM0Qd9ToiLCdWqCQHhq/qbPlPENrd4IzwG18HY7Dix2zuxYOCe/zTx97Jo9zH3pePv7mMiRbJZpXNq6y@zDYSS88VWhkLXuqnsUqLTKjBj710gY89JT4sFgkIkULu@KfCyZcCIfQx67qPCh@zQpDUkAGTwt3tFQC@MIVmNo1FIevMuY9cM/i5FyVX0drKfzGG8sKVv4SF2VTyMT3tc4ZtAsV@ur9eistJVFhdKj5ZKj2hndBZeJMfhpdYb/PR5Wl4Q6pEhO0sLT0ff0txQ4oQX2@iYI1e3lA/Ja2J@J5E2klJi1A9zbkdJ2YrquMLT1B5ojKHS4WLixuXCXD5iA2/p4jlTFmOBSWmgxb35bB@Rv0LtBNEkGuT3iHCkbAyEBsRPkLNA7JJvnIbh7pmuiywn5OvNhG7lYHQ8Bay1mrR6/fyWllz/YU1KNHwmumuFleLk3N0aoqmZui8VqYWHqjS@oun//Fve79mR9n1pcL7If0dZX/Nrqxm5ZEe6Ndj8@squ559jmIrX7PjAu2B6fHpf/xvqr/@F4KDL@Pn9M/6soG1Ms6u5ytc5Ut2fYUeSktL1O7/@ed/pj7My44NuVjnG55ixNYMRTaDHvMufVd19FK2pQuJWGHHLMAQC0Pam9MPGEbdLK0W@Zguq60qrkId@crYo@glng2zRmwqJCcZxp6CNCOpUEEDeQFpTCjayrLdMGYbYN4ETfXzQ38loh3Az9qcI24yNt14GMFkaF62RTSAOWmR9vPysF58kYnNO8oZY1OyZlRIbO20rF19vEbs8LYfjjrNtJWEma4XzeA6PPXBh37YuqQ9VS/q9n8ZFq6IJS9KS6uFNg73C2zHXRgwpPxg7P9GiqBOBkQbQzY69dSQRqB/gRBeHmcLIoV@O76TMvkkScsehE05w0rnJKYi4uPnyfUwuuMnqnSO/yUFHpkzdSJIK1faxx7V3Nsvq8xiXFDK8Z7XBTZv2ThWh8DIizXsgGWT73AfcDpo@uNXh2fshMS1EHVdivhBq9UI9LecM5cxqdI8Z@487A4qmbaEd0fsVNyYaPqLmnkrlHwHJwj5PAs6wLoIRwFt0SsZfoP9eNICwqTou9Y4VFxC1rYuq3f1rQpnXbmj6Wtp@ppGFFpC0k7MM1Y0NmUXE9lSwVHlMGzgSm1mw9RaZJI2D33@AwwiGZZ6G24JujvsAUlUS7qjrcrsYfN4L0w8ch2Kz54cLUrmaiebOD96poR4UEN3Qru@NEYCAlFwy7BQpt8H4gFRMWlGOz1H4vlNfDbxPTQY7sMeQonaYesk@KgsS70r5L7pjNiXUhEJdFxZ2wbbkdUjBh2H2IpT0GZw8JJxwVLtMm@2uKAZjjKngTYhoTIZOac6bqo4vWxbZ6@VRBH0IlMsLT1@srzydPUZspzN6d7OBoNKPnYBg/OAYLBGnaNNNt5XKpmFjLxCCurpJgF9FlhcwMGs69p1Tdjna/dBpVTUwIoZhnXNaTSkuj6uZJAJxGHoY0WgPUpumMnlXpSP0bGTjy33C/1H/G3iAzLDmXC0gZDeGoe3SWQq50ICDlRYMHNQnNxjRFBx9Re7bNhv7yPaRAhbV2F7amgHESBG58P@5dm5zR2@Dm11SBOGCM5xqbGDehWOkgBjFlbQRfWBQ93yvqgYeMfTPYBRLpYE6HwCnKaZjlsZaEtTzI4FWoQQWRMeq7hCtExHbXZm7uz1VW13axKxrJ2GjuH6tmUrKXccyQwBZJCr1@ruIVFXR7tgV1Itk7xUVGUWcEWUK7E7fABf6SYSUVtUMbKa9YZR7i6ylJgXk9CmSVUaR@A1A2ap@G1SGr9W0wsQxAhCfZoUCzEvvs@xSZbgZA8y5il4OVO2bETfdKKIA8zpxjKutijlQpxVYM65BSDObYoZ6UixjBHlxxonXpbRRjJH8YrG0YA2Q453quHMkpxmgq1uIwmAjazjhhbof31301NbNfpn@/2WB0V5o/pX9DtO8Xw7viWNb6ms6ttmCOxosWxzC5upX@GiRMxS1AFjEwQhfNuSFTFMogbU6tua9jKpj1Nz@yThCrBroJVwczqqJwkCvfAZyJzevMehONhdh9@V5fBqWtLEIVX0tJAjrrsntkWTuaTVGJKQ8h4gliZBxIFaEm6fSxheLNBZ8w703sUwdn17Nk@nWFY2VKS2bxeI7GmevZUyd7HFkmaLpTLG8S6@YL69kzdOw3Zf@6LFzPEN3njwx3gjf3/myP@3YI7aP4Y7HmvueFyG7BHuiMOGs0cnp2Hvz@CY0zGvwY1W56yD86G29ROdKHoWABZ4wBA@pPSxVETfbhEnKjf7w@LkegQjoaVlOAb8oc4/0Z1/UobM5cet8L9q5/N/584v684vl7HWzBh5rdpZ4db/Pj1OVMJc@sXM4YW6K8XcP9rTFd3TlTJW0xnD/P@9p/n/Rz19qnv6tIyICXLhIOHr7@Zm0USqB5v1emJu4Ts6aFcOeexnc6WLvVerkqHNQ7t7GZ1XoK2rP4z/qsZ/FdKIn5CGDncRsW1ovJeX7ak4y4tmyaccCk5W0hPpr4mMbvVXL1jJfkQvUCKk@WBrqDcqpJB78jG5bfIT/TGRvvHic1@cRbbrZJm4OLc20LIjLLnJFBfNVyfJXFqJ15UtjoGsNg/3dxb/h5DhIvikvdAIeQztddjtmpXE3oIdxlGndGes7gD2gd5zpFhFk5ORHWlv75hd5m6XahzYYmJdnL1JkKs23P/RXuoC@oaVlRtHRkQbX9c3uyqY5prthbyhvkuh2V3WPf5DXPpMc@mzstrXG4PbSBXoAz/Ni8k@bWl5@a41QGr5@IMJWPSo/B2z6v8C)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ztm92)

stinkhorn has a bug in `s` command – it stores the value in the next command, not in the next cell, and the next executed command
is the one after the altered command. Example: the program `7s 1.@` prints `0` in stinkhorn because `.` is executed right after `s`.
This is used to separate stinkhorn from CCBI:

```
 @,,,"364"<
@,,,"372_"^ s     < IP
```

Answer (score 2):

## 381. [><>\\.:.](https://github.com/More-Wrong/FishChipsAndMushyPeas), 16517 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 |\ 23nnn;
_|/$001 |\ 183nnn;
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1\0C0-<?MLot ~7+---<p>3:s4oya 8let d=5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1997*.; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdlWpukp17/UlWSyQBEmUQIAFkBJZkiq6e3Z73bZn1tPTnmi3Pb7tnvVsez0R453YWbd37JkIez9OOOaTf0D5sbHh2HD/g95zTgIgKJFSVXscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixJ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7O2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbwwX/HKM3TOsi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y090sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4Gx57aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYI8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7j3@@Ep4NcM@1iFTY8uYXUleVdlnpuH2rsbQ2KfH9@9fdc2yr0mOze5fz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuBx33ShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8PaMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/VqyllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T5xnYGrjwAbPYNw@unhE@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPHt@Ls3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NchX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@HaR1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9h3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzp0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0pZULSjFdLfuWYdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrTPcJTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzNeT5GPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjogXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPqdLEK5G2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENIdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMBnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zfqYELKjzymRvwNMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633jTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/kF9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reBjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@g@8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfElhlnKwUtxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@Q6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimzu8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5lSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08MgcR8IzbO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0dgnICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksIfE9MUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@4EjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zybYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmyeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/aOH9T8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO7Dw7tP957@YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4Xvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6OnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@XkyffMGK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Odj5JqvZoZY6UiT@fjo/sHTGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHuh2Y0kg8c4roo8q4aRcljMViFTitHrNB3edjq5vNGMVeODlvdRZq9KFBaFIBxIOAbXfA68SR0kRdcpM9W@9l/9vBaxj1iIkEUkIKceRaTKS3PElB6kUwW95R9kNAcy5A/I4onMjGpKPFgXUDueiR8RsIfzMxJIpPkbzUJYSH1vb1D7V4Q2J@yppkMEhpQFseRye3j@l7XgzZiO5YzcNgWxOHcYZAgsE1ri7k3cOxrNaSjIxY1hkuEQH9x4kYfw1hjviHBkWJFxVW@2Kjb3hlQabWQRSQRhgiUQuHlV/qpDuhalPvZ4RcHMIio@UwmNGfoAhRE4hC60NSNuJIDkyAh2c/PygKGy4XXenvgIUXW67DQPqELI@4tvFc6EsWUlZXhV2bpE@caxl858ytNC1x40wJDBGWHj588PHx88Gjv8@ZEy@eX7LlMuQCIg/Q6wAvJQ4437K1bvGtisRBcDPqGi90LqMAUBJRgtWjquUC4ZQwi8wysaTV8oTXxiTO0417yamHO0Fd6ZXd5E3qEnY8H9SOCoN2zUBhx@Wo1jufYfoaTydirKAr08uG0I4PQqrzqOpY@UCgeDAyWpagouhwe4byGtyoGZMabGzwGn9wC1mFOM4i6NXJAeKE1byQNLMHB06yVZQ6GIAvjwrjhJuWwBVNplB5ICCArK2HZiACTDXDrv4N6EnnT/qqqlXi7VjNaThGDYEvdH8Ju9A0QnRIwWgEqklesrHmneYfNgUojpKtAYkzeokkOj@FYYDFgJGnWFOX8ADlELXC@FGkF4ej1FGdzgUop@UyuqBbyCohlIKYBzyrhnJs00ifdoTRxJIAnOX2aN4i0wr7X1e2@vOUbgswC3/cRFDXbeNFs2i1g0Jt3KG@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu0B4zUGwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqusmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJXyi69AZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUbzLeh5N2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGNOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp1nXdcc@yj4BBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2Z/KiUTOkc14m4AW0q0WzGAaU@dhrdoUvwZmktmQwRBfnomyBlWFYiLp@XIP1OspVMxSFuMp4GslyLxwEvtODoUaFxRoA3ovvmDFAJHROGuOiaAhFIWpzC7vqFMR7O3WiAcNYNuGycQV/sVcEtPUjFo1TyDY8fZeiWJP2A7@XhgLnFyTvkl8ZzTt0FntOmsrQzKhh3T6X@yJnoyqcyCE1yZLiMb8QVSYKRkHw4JCr2I9PDLqzbhjP1ojONKydAMXVwPR5OgVgG29PS0KrMsWB0hw6Lb@4CdBau9@BQgktXEl8ACwD0ujLcSESRK8HFEuAuaEORCXSRtmLRrIxKmeCkJ5ibzxfGr@UwtSrFYRlMyBzYjmtIgBKIIdDuKdqTJ9SDdelDmvm6ti7h@9KQhoK3aQBFvG85OuGWk@vIetB4FIkP8jlEeWr0BAvoRx/Io8zrwjV6ypZAq7SOO4QRAkqDlFgLa2vkeyiON@7JkxlEFRI44EY9uXQHTOcZ62maVujm@5XAD1sFIHsIlYRSqQ0ibuAlqeCZ9Cv5gE8LBTL646N7B3zuhAZbHF5xHq09cnpT4Ct9uempYQ/S7ADak2k7IxPQEMR/c2I9dZwJl/LBsm5mhgvN5mhq6TTnc3Va5sZ4XafjWDQVdFPURfip6@mWziehAt@9Tx8Br//8@FlNrkQCKfrp6Ma0cR5ydbIcn4fRNUdabw2WhzzeMMXNvIjjVrDrE8mM71FAj6m/5xPqKHAvonvQpXANxXcvofsI93sCr@zPIpA1dPQDlikg7gHFDW@@47mauUT3tTJYGE6lcJxxXOT2XNXI/XTS7y85Z8n5RELSZC2cc@TM94IuyYjRLOV5INwYuhQmCqhAYcL9oWvDFSkc390ihyuLj8JNCEPDCpYWnwLHgstnMOhbyFeB0IIsOt/DaQCHPcZVEiLduPbGusCEetfmM6CzjSUeWohtUAeCwU1BlkbYVJg/912lLmQ7/pqlx8mqAzI/Tats1/kqN8pULhfnFD4rv9kGENv1arDhbl0wTCkeD4MRVMobxKBi0sL@taKG2zQ8mmwXKEpV8BQQJ2ZaRmrOigeti7jiERr6TGw2Zx9ltM9BLsHdkpt3lIFRpT1Oa/BVDXziPg/bmTMJOD4MxSeuu0OgMyw1W0Yl1M/U7jtWT@KrZNBgGJevsIL8TQrhLk5/s65husEGTtpBy6MifY3s/bwG90qV1q8HiOwWDQFB9zlnFyfp0wvWgCHvVPbGljlpsUt54rSH/k4p@@q@Us6Duq4@9wR/j0uN7T39@NNGpsUhCCMdV75KvBZnwfZkYJyBUcJ95GDCnToTc0KcAO1EMLG8qgyZmtEiCWQfYPAEqixMyC8RZv3CuFiUpW@ApJowMOfefJRmRvJS7lv6ZGLYvM3x5cf16ObrRH4yNUp@x190qLAMrcwAZ2qiH2Sxyp4d3zt4@lSGlusl4ge4glOB7qh3h8CgrCt0gMlo4Svso16cfYRxkii2C9DVQPpo@/GhUVeh0YP8Aakj7RgYbgIck7j40gVnWu@iiJxD8xGE@626E8JRCCxhJKFMBKyyMv/PbS5q@fmsQItPESYB3Yk7FcCtmZSntvla9mCgIb4VgsS5sArjRW0zQVRsU036G@pGuHQMEhYxjVCCRoNJb4DKQWCRtVpVvgcAwqIA5g4Qu6JIVUG72GtqUPU1cAaWhiD40Wtv2YtGRiq3UpurQNHmMn8DOi9/BC5CWAbtGSuT3UxQf7/WkXke@Fogp9zPSZy@cvqiwja5QeRzzhQ82DBFRIf2Vy3vk1rehQWdDEkJTcVgQQKSEPOPB/htlvyJ8oPMg9HIIZFk5yHSNUQ5u7ggHLJNjREOwaQyXhmXgfQJhOmhA6V56B8NiHIH1Fv9jSTYZ5uCGIhZyyu16MNZeOX0CncqnYrReJw7NO0Th9Z7QlM7I6t55AjD2KMT63pM3IRKj6WgYR54WG1d7rxRp0@PFQFo2cNfUCcHmlD3eWFgInXlKb1obn1FysubSJaS9ben0kgLZia9viWkVC5R4H6nY64LCkjAfWHBe0UwIFLYnjU5J6vBWQOcioHxCAgXl14WRb@6/4gt4d3fR@u///M3eoD/67UzhIECZx5DQxuGbqwpqb@2svyoaKHH6orlE@RTy9QJMWS6DWRXd6FIuhUaVoOmRXhJguF/hEsKfo1D28QHcI03NDOec74iGLxXJ7JqUc0GktldF/bKfiyeFC3/gGDXIyRwJsg0KBKRLl4JxowvwUREbCRjt2cq2DTFqDHzeh9OJ1P@BMb11ko0x3jf1Df9kJm83lENhe9cv6HKXf1k2nOk8ckg5FMLK8IuSk9rwBKwA/5ycBuNq4vPC8h3ggfvdcEWQ5tyRq/bWoVnT72x1CEpvMdt1BFGN6TgWvy5LojpH94LDeuxZlr0eM@W6EOHhuLvhlBwr6kUQZp5Bc2W3pkjDzL88FYW7iwAilPrplKZ7Jql5fF4fXyUJCl@ubw69kzucnysmiNQ@H5Wic@iUYH9Ha631CoMV@ZItyStFzGuJearNiZcCxquaVIcPHxBJzBubOQ4IHWnlu4uTDc08UU@gmWEdTPS/rDxxOw6wA6MmVqUVS0YOiIDBpHMYGvcIiHcTkyPyPYHcxUag@MkUmhaTQKc7gS3jK5pU@9B0PhWTdwQG2kksrMOU13nDO@17MMQRFP@XD2ivVmZq/cgTpLVtXQYx9cOB0uTgzj5eEtDPTM9gx6rEXuyMqOTrrXSfbkLBNN@0Wm825q1Z1qOx57R8yYEDVzAAn@ubtBRXJq6LdFkeNR8Aw0K9jgsKlS3Bo5VKA0UHR5ra33q9pHu@@/3pXAhhVLVWyhUwP44tuq/19L1E8U9ua2C6MCii/tbI8YbhthVZMpfe1lfOhAMcOFudcnuZ0oUU1b4VN@ahHHJ5UyfB@@fY@hYh9pg6BjPiZ0G7g4jlEtgmLicxf55UsvdnFrv/YjSNbDF2woRqdwTy4DBip7XqpRpGfUDY6iZzPuTqL41NabGSkHjqPPKwGP1NwgZ75@pjF@MTX@mHhcH8GhKGOqNLxm@V65xnEbbjcREt8yucTsrs0zUxsB9j1F0fgKGJ2i4HmNgT8dLtbokndlPb0bZcBx0aae3lDv0@VA6VLqFU1rizz2D7hslJi7h4QaxWj6TyfgMTGTFZclykySVDeO@MvlzKWFyWaS8CIurbG7EuDoNQkt0C@JaEqStE@wpcLms2KZtTOb4fE9q2nEc60NqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRetSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@mnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BvkdvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7Gs98EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufRBcftLef906eadPOO1Aw9peMzSmMC55zsQZGxLZ1gW1cKKHP9fR0GCR@uedQbpRzgeMBO@fF/6tsuVAdybjMb3aY2vq0YOiSnRm@Ta@qc@3ptCmSMcdyG@cUUf2HWV/3wotga8mMR1z0h3ioXHeso2B0@kOzdsy7SuqUIIpH259L9kVMWMy6R46y5YJ6HXnMraXWtT/Gb4O11W6P3vEh7XQcAO/smqGjo5lS2P9pOvx2VA0sQpOCEd6Iz@8XaHj75XXU3OyABrZyxRO7/JlCTSsy7u/e2ItZ0VnJBZk2N9VsbaVEpOODLlkZIDhUdclu7zPLdLFsln@WJehaCkpR5F9KR@Cbn/vD80OmpF5W3Bfal9Lm5ZWDnL2cDrwrhNMPl3fAxYNH@unLWgvc2TKGsYs3fZf69CsWQoecoR3G3iuqXHjmkr@xkUVCqdaku6Y8GrDC6puunYOzTLHHn8yqb92Kc7fywSy@NX1Qo6b@Wph2q@YntHnSyBouo1FHDku7kQGHkTq4ko6zqAjMeeMFydctjMAoi5ZbBE4CLuObVm5TWh19YdjpvT5Y2Og417rh@YEN2uuaBXUZFdtL7oV9tenumd@fQolW9fYUGMDX4Z0o0f70bYC3iN9YHYfLFVEmEkfwf5OT/5aav7odL0uzoamhzuaQsMNE1PY5HgjxlbXBrlhRcir8/ahsopFB@LHIFeGXjW37ozneFpsTqabptXNCc2y@u91ouO6TWA3ZuJsOhpPPf@1Og@0Zyo6Cz06IXfvzATg0msgrWyoW5PVM9WRKVfgwvxBcWFcx41/YVrOgH1RyjBg2oAJQ@Z8RcO5C8PzE9yQ49orWiKl/Z7LnjjRIbm8YK@hbo0sk0zbnNw8mzOZ4Oac4I2F4SMHnlBQHuJT3v1QCNLxaow8vJ3XXxxNvmV8h5b3zJm6XQONob6RqFjgp2rsB7uP8USHg/pSzqJSWtexoHuBwVrZZbqOPZ1I7tS@cVQo3DgqVFDbVKQZsMTXDx49T0ZbA@3Wvo0LDfSRLUxrNwxcaWSmDYzYejq6HDqQJe5xPUlPaavwLXH2UJlTl8j1PWeVvPNkDgPIewtMQPyno3tGF5cNb037sfPIsR0YjcZAKEdPDX7mf2mjx@qIGO0hnmoH/PRuTeYZgV0zCHFuQx8bHahfa2F6n7GIA76nT/Q1QxHNDZL8F5pubSum1THcVzTpFzGvE2mXM/TAmJFssb7B8D4oTbpdzhLjfNxSH1lasfHGjmPzJ1HbDLzURzdTFRgK6PH@C@UybsRfmhdYKZ8tF/XolO8SMXpcKcW6srpGx7H484Y9SbbJ9wTorml4ykPUcUBuhRyTgPvybqQhxRtpyEI0Ak72VPdokX61qLEAqc4@YAvQUHe7Dq6E@YYbdudEFBPcQqbDvf1840AHED8DiqV3p76y0NuyZY06I3qsFRgitfnU6OCpoA5p85jos@uVyWeGfFUGkR1doQKAgFxhpy6wxBOQRpK3D1tLctQyVs0xPYhSr10up806km0a3Tc6zpo5hK/F3PSSP5RZeUzGNXPVkW5Es8iKTifdV/ak5a1rwNBYhjQZuiDzK5ObprcDNSsr1kOmIwMXmZdXYdayro43pMI6q9fTQ@LqGpKv6w9oSaj3j/OH0t5azhPBw//o7icKDMLtQi5QPQKk6/YVfMj81LX91/u0wCeON@mbsyPIN54CWEdOsFh5iAIv3jPQtLWuEFB79tTisw@DyL6rUY/EMYm0MEuSReR6YkiGfSqRIrjZ9RI5/NCXsofaeydGT/L1IOBKg/QwOP8VBvPfKxZQo7QRN3uqCkfsrJDzt3@uQu5ZQBmA33Im0tijtzL2nhw@PDqWx566cnzaG@LpiGt83JJiBa2UiUxJvdLdyHon347WM72JcveZKu0/PJQxwBp88xUNCV64Mrf0WjvvGWhxVfS1UhD6GpPVDOKD40cPU4sjmiyxP3SdkZGMeu8/e5bGkyafPFvpHY19H3pH35mtjX54oKrJFc33uU2rg@uo54qU1kE6NkAahcb4gOtluZW56jpjo3c8HxufwuCJFNx7z@QLawv5WD81B9gLWXktoqijsrJcyCUjO7NB2Dbc8L2uPk/MMVLLLr0U/lq7HQU5h6ziZldzDzet@F/lYljG34nwYZHUzPXWGtUjrOje3zdjqqquw/MzvQ/1yvJrK2s5wKr1Ycs5fY@lZMMXXqTQSZpAq5LMW/eRF6URkG4FHzg97zuCsbN2G8xNAELnwsoOf2bYc92WaC3rJvaiArFxU9uNQb4w3mNBKtzhc4rKyleu8YVb6lmiS8bkLQkfu5Eo@/t3D2@L8NTH5c2hPn78nD3RPVRCcnPAaI6N98jxgjN6JeG8FWrAW7uc2nMBlHYjvMF4dX@usGe623Ps@ez2RTg6g4pDOykXDmGhjQIZljkzV41VXT6v9WT1NqPb0uaHOJz5Eh8cVU7jA3r37X@mqpkMqR7Ct5rh1ltqJujgLIEmfY767KJex4chaegi3yKDQ3KlNPrQmOF2FD4bvEqoXzm@FW4Y@4rJ9cPJTX6lG/xyN6R3zQ8dWVbOqDcAzN/gx/Jy6P3Qsc6Gjryvu4a3Yv/xygzdVJDyDQUpR6izry2dFhZ983oWH48u@K@VrfXYmLi58dDpmLmVZdjro5JJ9giVpV/397dT6C5tbxk4/pEPbl@d3tnUWJnQI/3Nag@iNCcrvYAIGsMpHYm47r28QNoBntewBybXr8juOpMDst0gmIUnnlfvRTDH96bj9TkG2oifpLhKzpcCfgYys3Pmsbt4NG7Bpq@Q/XF/3Gr3dTwtCycGUc3og@O9oHUdPVO0SIqLXHz@ZMkZD49Ojp5F3FxjNlsn9EqzdTLkSp9Fqo@Pc0vJbtdfnK5A1vrzRsBuAD0O32v5IE7sPnl2nSSg@DacjKzA5xPdXsyYLlVYz5nQScOVnk/mM9pGubKmh3wX2yo/t7vCeUmwhwHZNCFtT2m3UbN@u72uVR4bn9PaA7BBbMLZEg7UV7xkzHLDIIcUZW1HdU4WzM9Sdp@Nh6Y9W@k1WheHdpEmXnmru8Eee2Y5Z@xhqFVoHXnQVgPXTw17HXFadVhRKmdv5sKyV1iqdfXCv17iv9ZVyd11jNoVmoEbIm6iJhj/aVe5H1g@1ZK3hv/kWRD89rD7loPz9z1zOro9MIFNpW4P6N5A/q4CNG8Phh/7OBk6rn170KA5VSp3jffMxMZ7hxzNu8575KHT798e6MBzbg/0aGpNTJRZVgd97Ewt1CCwyu/AHax0r2/Xm025Il/35KeuodNGNfZ7aV/nEtdSwM@Ge3LwWYVEwob2kFz@hlX0oDvqtU5sol7XTTrUDmEvLtiGf5AcPMTgaLp/dB7VP5r21MCz7/zLNpPaJiRTq6n5MtvBj0ZVmJqhNPE7eGWuZS9IrME2z/1j4ZWKesk2akysiMw/mB8qzeaKnwEwqqyFQjHpRGWbE/DZDA6VM/qGCbtgNBcGwreaz4BNVqLqNar@sXvI0@b5k8MnB8@O946fP2tkWpf@sfygFLYNqQXKPz7K9kQovI834LG5GnhSB2FBcvR9FZxD84JyMfxm03LRaktFWxRK3ME4m@e2rSikmUCRLiF/kshTI18cKcCJww5KTBXkK6WocCUBpOsA6oiDFilNqLQKy6xKeKwDv7hp@/5XP3FGvvgJvAp@BA8T9jV3Q0scOE7PT9Ez2O1XkOL9vcOHz58esCCDi1ZzZvYmw1o5zxW7c20pUE99k7Zq1ljcjxKHuqrV4vfjgJi4HGcV0iVBStWhoUOwADuohcKPvcUSmwQfMBgPK0X5z99QLuMynjpIQth4kKk4JAttnhrKxsYGO4ZGwu49Pfz04CnD/B/cI2dEEYJgx3iQ/c9@3OOfJQkUTQWf/3NHxNyRoh4hqswi0PCwUEKBOKe@O17/EUD6DAipegi/PxJ@QEkQ6PM00G7PSEfkFf2BSVLpxT9a6Kt3DBKiJhR8ygAXuFBVo@uxU9MzUdEE5qGPmhOXGzvuiSNtoTLbwy8c4ncUdfpGDmR9ak@4djJfR1EMWpoc0pw026TM8i/qiJGA8e0NaOwdA/h@5tkmcJGTCnsFLREXkSpcEYkk1ePXogSgK2SSkFeMBLymatFTmq7y7tf@iTKoMjBPwPwd3zzL3AXbr/i2Pph/lZtfKNjQrqtmXOQlmiFUp@qXgGckxD/iPvJhR5srf1kgDjVIBoSVmSOoplPCOgbnKfCnBPR4ASfR@BQqDZob1Jiv9IWnZ7itBOpzrSgKNimURWU6cmPM@P7XK3pdC/lCTlUgk9JpAJA@xDDAg/0cYDJZgW4inJrj2kuQb7a3t5mIE1JGrVDlNats2i@y4sswo5sQVjgbYuYaDOJAlEUM8Kv70WD0SalJjIrUK67GkXD1HBiWyB@HL7TbPiJElgBkcRwZqNl/ht8AnQCb5usn7uBXMyMf6dn0AUkqjElkSoqCry7lsTOB5gOddPEZLq4uBfd/8yEQFX96/Mu4pBYY26N8vWctTvkHXwPy@5qMNICDymaujqbRuhU/QxDPEERFXNV8Gy9Yc9K0Wwpvmwya6Q9XNGYbzL@sDNa0WV7uvetKYRNXVboistjuM9vBmbf7UBiW0BQtq6iF5KJIudzKIvkl8pOB4qDmqQtIDsgUkIyuYb5yxt7e/sHhJ0dPnl1TfEoh41eDAd2vb6eakpxutEJDPFqs5Sq5e1959uju/aAiFpkuRKgxEH6/JOpNJVlMqCPIxQGtq0VblcOrpVuf48@4Coer@c1qN2WNIl3Lh5r5gHTpkIR0n446Xk1cK63CVj5/U5YW8JQI6H1@Tv1aVhPJ88tGC9heOxa/3hJWdIQXMXkLOwGYmt7WpoKN/XrhsGDhN6uP8WuAXrQvZlf3RXEzi3r1UE3GxDlZaB70HSIekfIGyQCJFGQlCLq29x1xJn2hH1Pj39TmCvmi6sYiGS5kbsJ4BNRx8HlupCIL7b6@Ytuh7g0tsyMEat64gttAD2eo25araEskBf8bMTzhhP/B7lllJtOOyEQSqR3BSrObdOUG8JICdGjk7p5MvSF74oz5NwNo58s9IzA9dYD83pvymTKDfTIdQbg@vZ4atAoJlFuCyIDJeJhVzksBlfBV5c5SqIwY0mugwly/4PKol0/MkvLQmPXMAdD2RDINFO0jVW2xUJ0uFprU59pxkepsUQs3dsWPUftAFO0fpFN5tsiA3tBl0@4Zs0T8LJ6stCB9dI@ffXYaT4qr2hLpdvaVHfeuKnkOs19Ub6Yk@sTvnYEG5VXUoly@TiXA7Spgrmww@GBZuSwPPYE@QFlDzv3ZxH0IRmAjEv2RPmaJqc0VNcqMrIlmwk6TBjupzpXA2iyVIoEKXuQhM4rZJxMfvxO6PWcJpYbfKAVXz@7h6405Zg1VlltgpkSSbBM/JLgPHBeqLk0KIARDlAqBrWETAjEDcsQ7icwbOMRBfwgLL1J3ucKbvqtGizUO4oRKzep3WOTDkMuco1guV/wKXaaKZQat7zo5lBUAe43OBXw9YNfX4QQ4A/FXFmILQn6d4sUo3RjPyANf@RNkJxZR3BzohGIAa6FWuTt08U4c2NBXgD@oVJ4f32@XkorIQiVSA9fs4WIi//ZAKOL5X4uCbqosBY1XuUT3MUZDdZ1trqUKtUbepw4jXiGpsSgafJXHgbDsLdqmqt7Y6v2Ifi1AyBwOAP5h23YADlWsBrOMK/xWE/uf/SyGzEZiU1VP2u5pKp7PVOGhVvMszz7abErSZiNT293UQYqavJ41QSZXtnL3To1hv3c4UJqiyLIspyhb5@fn8ftbT8wXeVaQeqZWeD2bX2YL2dezy6xaen0yVgsN@fWsJZZq6ZMWe/Lk87ftt0lxdjp/LTYTWmz/6EJUcyjyxypldr5TyMZOyiB@QrqMnbA3cJ30Gf7J/KYXMeto7vRBhI2LLNZsAsZVsSgqSiPegj@J@y/h4oJ/oy7X5Z3W27fJhq5PZnNmmubY6/XgdobAQWrJZwzk5TtA6XkEhTXpTRIUXqNZ//p8Qp6x2Z4xGEwP9LqG57Dl3XZ1bk7vTx598VlwPcfrzdNItDf@l4tTqYQkNVbMU1Taej6G30D@s59sXKbPn7S3/@ybI8XYwNcRvr5z@QjNz9T8RxsbH929m8ulNU3j5idfPPnFvb293L10/kkjv5OTMhvbf/onGxuatq0pGy3PU1vxxsnJ56KWyYnyn/0o3n7y5OueV8/@n994W1fxUYTHKSsCnYAry1Qw4rMEt4o81vtesTcxaOVqbE6/dixwP99gan2n@F@@d/Q6NonVNeUzF96T2OtYoRTjRjCALRvYTmP12DYGK1zG5kqtVgNj8b/8W4hf/wTgoM98Gx71fACrMI/VpRpFuYjVC2BQNQ3S/b@/8Y1IDjmZqBEbF1y7rAGXmCtq4k4Lri26tgVUzillFCUIZ0@GE8NhaumOegctJljgZRv4lQNj0ozhV@DZ0S5jTxupVKoltyW45Bc0SaSoqtZU1TtADqSPtmo1aYtx9aPZbP4OqlBP0pTWwIER07jz2T/EFVvlWP25wT0VYoWN3Zf36nUoU7ae3aqn6PI7EvWpYkl0nF2RpdnLOIggjdbLh4zrTK6LmZImptPp3TbZZ4graRa2JLz4MxYLXbDLsqtuS1EgiO8a@/BwsQO8/vx/@/Pv//n36Pd9uv8Dai@1e2Zf2YJAp9Al6nDtVirdel2su@J5E@11aEeZSqlSUtqXzcQWUKDWU6ZmPr6I57PxZ/wL7SpjzSTFhouSrfvJo70eWzjXuUs96uZ78MDkwPxSkGEJa2QOsXYtHAyt/j5vqXFab0nIENWkhlrItyQeqx5cZdbYhWoStWJZbNW1vHbEdtszfrHhpsecGEiGhQCPfn7ri7LVQ5@FrR51itWDaPVFmA8NF@ZXiDUaSsugASFwY7sblY1SpVDRlHZ9/QVNM2qloIZhPPFip7Hw4piNLRAaC5vmVbegKkILC1ow@5BwUFnvM9lNtZQtqGLVN2ltJlahkWhZSRu0xYwqhr0N5/fh2oAf/eEKrfjcIBffmYJcvzZYRd3Sskr@o8KBhuPrLVc0rwKME6zb6XTedDvAdeh6R@/q6kSf6jN9rk86086sM@lOuwy7zPKMftbJOyVnxmb0l6VYNq9uxu5Qo37b2GBPORVqsVRwNVO3Xs9lue0byeDgLUnOLCbE/gGuuqqpbAvGpww8gCkjI8jM@FNVgcWA0Tpvvd1qvN2CDlpPbRNxbNUlP5fwktu7rZR0edkAc7Xq/7frobFKFzdB4VqXqdT2izpwHy/qjRSAfOGDlCVGQOV2vbVNPmFifmq@93YL@Bcptd3Yrjn7dMvUQaQWQNxeyuXubkoG0y7ErG@CAJvalKQNHBIb/hABQVv1VFAYTDoBTML5@fvc8ZwTLzi7K7xAzIM@fLl9Wb9sbF9ebm/Df5uel/4bXC@3r/3ptbjWhFn4t5CwNBtKvak0fVLRArus1NFFVppgqMMbwjWyWqnVQANccuu/zb@cXjxDF8xyS4ZcC7EtthVDTZrZ2JYQe/nuy/8F7@a7L38fuUUGP6MixM6xUytbKGuWucgJD2Y/stkjftlgxjuwogs6PKqjo80fNi5HKcpLmVX4jH9CLRWSMg6/baffRuUcMnsJQa9RPiZqpYLYTqlzjcW2xUKRiN0vXLvi8fg/eqmVi3E@TYPaJV56nvcokstFPiFwVcuoknpR5x9Q4N@6@YVV1z/6hXWXELsoM6MC@EkwjhghBu0opiiSBMNVfXuExw9woURCmfS09rn0fE/CSRR9QstgXT5BUDs8qJXLdb7Gs/mEOs/WvS14qvA/2IBisGYfwjb7te4I2N9mP5vXmqhtPyZ1XuPv4Rv8seMu/p6@xh87foO/pxP8sUcd/B2/xt9eB3/HI/zdfY2/R2/w93yAv@ZXslm1Km6eE2ZSalm93JyJhKFqbKfe/MrEnVcsw26YvZb/IalsrsySseZXjFnXGE8q3LEf/@l3v/nNeK0Wl@L0eZ6c6rhMTcYYBsRvjDKWrEJNqBkVSujFq7vxrzRIRM@XWw0M0gJfIVZjm@qmmrEy3YzaUTtgMFnGZZlhZqj2VBJlMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9MBvwyYDIzfZYZsIydsSEY@IJp0s5M0NSH1wB@fQDkws/EDbcdNdNlkJCFTB19/FNtY8zMRbspNFiciS8NkEVlVc7IBbOFn0xqiC9fNpWtllYuMRmbndxuvGzGW2JTRDX6WjnHOnNjo/lShKE7I/LmiS4s5nkg4FZjSrOpcEwCkgjRl5ft9sHje@22gsNU85FztPgfHY2i1hv/oyPn0ZEzcuB/dHQEncuop3ZTQMd3d2tA1/3XTqxe3WlWaFgIhoaYsr3TrGclNBdSQPQ1dEt94LWACO/6RlOIn4GAcQaySTUBEspZ9bRaPSPDZ9wKhjaa0TH8n/kG/00QqqF8cwbXKYElGxrPPmuGJm5QPjsDp88YyGXhHwTAqPW/wt/8b@v/6DlLskSjlUycX24n6EriL5k8vzy/9J/1ZCLhWxLb8EMHsGOU88s6GinQOZgaiWQreXnJ3eCZSG5zgHVIZrtOcRfhYOCIhUlSsvyR@K/7hqT9qxmvAl/MZe98hvpRTKwyfbHvptmcZTLJaif4QgiuIusXtLkhWaXPQ252GmrrT39EX4HZSVKgfK5aVbcYt2g5rVrNBbZiqVotBZbNRKJ8/apndtQCyCe5XDJZrYJlJwCbASvEbbC3KVZjTXi27tzhiZS0i4sAZjZXSGVwv1O1GqSUh2QNT@/6NPn88Ig@oAKkJh/DLxdxUpLI0OeX8BN/cbEi3rmT6Bm4q7u3s5e8c0crZy4uQpfxGJzUJad2u2e67Ta6Zy8uxLZI@2TKebBnShcXaqacUuNJx008xm9DQlIJSWUfaXVKtQyUXssVwdvPQH57u5Cr1ws5cCmU4klcc@ckHvIbF@NVMXZOZVBLRU4BxSo6R/cPQV/GcYKdX8aoQlkun0wAIU0Cl3gZw5@LNJePSPl8EjBzKfKQarnMgyZZrpAopcr@r7YBUjuwQfyHvFw2ldsqbu0CT4w/b7bqQppcPTdq6mXt3KjgrPtltet/ZRuVkBh37mTLgKJSptoU2u17e8d77XYNxjJkpeCBjkTdBdTN4sYr1V2qV7WUZ1CB3FGKw5DASoBlRdvKqyXEimD2UakQ4EDg4tMG2xA0euNDKHNUbYAjyDeQWg8u1mMdNsCLDVCaYyaz6GIW4/707HbDQA6/fN/QSnFJ4AtcjPAS/G6X5W0SRu0nD/f2D47T2rbEYtr9vf209uz53ZiK1vzCTt5ZtD892Lt39BwiPHl4sPfs4OPDTw@ePwF3j50troDK@8/FO2paYT9jnwmv3De6YejG1DDaZ9Pp2Wv2yjTbJtSeNYVCOQOXeUYbyjLWF@Wqwt01Pf3VK90d08Xe/fDb73743737ne@@@51vv/ud7//0y@9/G@4fw/1d/v7uvynn8fnTL//Z77777d8Bx/8A9x/B/ZOffvkb3@A32f8Y7v8Ucftj/46E47cAsH7lp19@70c//fJXfwD3v/TvH1y/f@0nq@/vf2v9jfG@97s3h/nuv4X79zisIOx3f5u74fta@N/m4X71B@/@xb/j/z/1f2j8nXf/4o/x4Vv@6Q/@9D@9@@a/17TSn/7rd9/63rtvffPdt77z7lv/WHv3G/9azUQfv/vu@3/wV3/4e3/1h/8j/X9Mz997n/@7H/zTv/hf/@J//4s/9O@fwP3vwPSTv/j30FX@9g9@iP/v/cHf/tEP8f8//6u//YNf/9tf@Z/I8Jvc8P/8y3/Dn3/9a//xb37rO3/1k2/8za//5G9@8w/@6v/41f/rN/7jX//3v//X/@Sb6PibP/mrP/qVv/zmt//yW//8L7/55Zrnt298fvke7l/@A7i8fz7fB877lOtDXb78ufLz98HGIhVoJ9C6f/ndb/wSNPB/wdi7b/8Yz@vBveb/Y02lMD/mtv8PGLTrZUafDJjg/vV33/4uouh/ABTBP8TXd0LLkg@3fGdhAbT@1opIv/zTL//5j8gWMyp1WsbBwbqklVJbINBslcv@gO2v8ECUX1qGFgLwU/oOUqglv@8gbXv3w2@8@9E/fvfD33z3w1/B0VrKldN7aUm9ZXkMAubfIxwGLLxPOAz4Oaafoqk3KfU52Njnvufnn38utC8UPBi6ewGun5MTvxj3woOjvlfgh@54kpRdsKjZN2bYRZNpWdu2q@iySZ5NYEm4U5gRxhovX7ZwPRbcMDMpYkW2AtYon2WzlJ/PGePLPugOgWZbZJzhk1zReybgY/FfGGcCS9FcMF@RSC2MZPDj@Ulwo5CHZFKzcLGJeDXGmaUt7kLryJRursywBLNZagZCMBgghRR43QV2vFZLYcQazw9YedbqJUZZSaVqUG6MzeOk2yUEMbtLUCBmLfWUtbdqMx4xhfDqATpSAjo9FVVNTJVq9yDB2uweQ1gInMC@fFmrl2qzOoJ7y/GRmqXuUp4QWC01q78Fe41gQjwhdu8tZKVUS6XqJUwQC8mrJ93mlZSnwlHZUyzl1wG88TjAzi5jH4lqSeSLCBuIMB4an6lFaAwIwcG/mdryi0P/wEj3FiF8g5LyU2Hcf4dY1R3OvWIAgCtJsiwzuHF9foftgveMg0pRsvBKcQgpahHUAkIHhvNDKSFF9ZsiC6Qfq2198IXAsDCbm5tCrC5mxSOZUKcozD2p0NkI3C6I4kWFiYWyiM4GHRQJ8gLxq5T@ZhwX3uKMA2Yfpfi9u7vFPoJi0nvhJjAplXVyToxD2U6lRA3g152U8ALEEgHaKQG6EORZjRb6UkI6zZhci6EfOzo68jNBDi9qQgqauZZV0Y7LTdPpNAYxZDktp9P@W6Y3Oci@QSZf/y1vInLp4@lM03JVkJ6qDJ1YVNRRQQRGx7dv30Kt0P6ryiEIn8zfiqXlSuQJDlxdjmXNgxNFWq4scMmcqYUcYwmahIUryfDoTAIaUlLg@/Z5NoIrEddKpTiFBPzLia1gb15BpQaBc7CxOmY1uLhQWMonA8/9I7Z/9OjRwePjcavFBIM@B2@0x67TNTwvgX57j@/xMxtauZCMNRoI@riiIYkRDioZos6H954ePqswXmy/EhKUsSqtvPoFLatCbDz@bDvm700S8YuGjvgMn5VF2RJaOQtRY3Uh1jVQ1MAldRSBq6wqPPIGd50ZSPVpUUyrBRT1kriACPn4RWfKUN8uV84DvQpPcsjb24QBoX4u0fIGGqG@CkK97u/qY6pQf3ZwDBGOj5iqZWSh/jmbyZigdCnUrZpl2IPJcBO3x4nNjBgp02Yjk8afls3CU80V0mq@2NrYsM4lTLNJ1XaO@xwvwXouYTG@ChcTviqwr4ITXJAGbl5k/s7Rw6Oqv30PNdsl@B4@Uc1DR0sKONnNwQnj6AUj05XFIiG28cUXE1avg4QtHd4XYkAvhizYwSaZPXkoUzX3pq5BvgPGeuanJn6qUu6Z3tjS59B5ABuxy8vLPkA6vM@0ukZWHqOHz8suuXTAfDnThZhdqdTeqrmioJ1UKm@zmiaAg7Cl4Ba5DWgAtNNgS@G/qgeJZLMlBWiVKorwymazAs4eC0LFEBjtJnmbqdUk3gazOZU2kwj49RN9VtPCyw87@2gRNpvhYdEHPNhg4rJM4Ffkfr6tIJANkIb75@hb21W/e2bu3MniNEY2lwnnK6jE7BLqZjObyyLG8XxSK5Yr@gspoii2YoJlTFivBuZYEx58Sk5TYyJDG5KNbCkjxBqxhvD/98tfK9oe17MZdVsZg1EHY25b0cHYAWN@W@mA0QRjeVsxwTitZ9XMtjKtC0zY5kpxGercqYkTY4Y6uLmbWPcMqy/jsaWaSAlo4ravZL4eRKz3aj2nO8UdI9WebNq24eIJeR4hlxOrjo3qGmuouIV0CrBE8lwY1M7oHL9g1AYyagBybd0SenLH6c1lbzK38ACQ5bi1ODCW8cBjAd0AFganzXay2VylwVry2BnvCFq@mGqoGRh78FZLaS29YewUi5We3LUM3d3JV/KldA/PFvkLaDv5TGUgf/7o4YPJZPzUoANHO7kyRECdeajdaqdUyedbjYYophqUTAu/D87pmrSxAcTA0HsSvHF5zZO0Ugsi90y3VovHd7KqJqmVbKZ0KSwQhzjHEtYFjJrCkqUR7@c@6ajYjg1UqpLW0@Y5YaHS7/cvt85TC4ugn0vcBvi5lPR05zy0VqVIuAqbpiVz4Qkueh/Qfe6vHFZELV8Sq43qwl4siNXWpbA7MnqmjueMmpnz67EKQM051Bgk1GTCZcV1nEmlY/Qd11gEzKqFICDP0PUAOfEyTK6ZwRTPrydXiASanV@HksuLl2GsIFvC5SXgnSMb0O5rPK7TftyGWs61DoB2QfPZDpQhY7DYixdCbOvpp9l6Har6PFfUcvlcXssWCvmiBgNVOVfIl6CzZQqZvKYBlFy5VC5eQrtWlLcx@tYh2z8P2nuFvvaQ0CtcXWmjxZJvH5vWeSkr8XwkktXLy9hbIfbR0081GFnXXgkYrT/VpHotmy@DKYsmLQsZZoKmSVpWyqqSmsX/LQYN/@8fXoO/hk@IldWEY9Rh9BjGW@ARbPYQdaFMHHbs4NewBuyu0V0TYn@o02bpfdfxvL9HmLu6fcK97plccXDo9UDHTwJ6I3MyXBPi@XiE6o8M9x8MwsGoAxlEcsgD3IWHaznOqgBF9vzJmlI@ClX1AzK4rn4I/vTw4wfHkffxwd7@A6HA7h49vnfllfcD5dnDg/vHobXIfYOo@RDELx48fHjV6r9yR8@f9qeOi7dw/@h5bvEInfAsrpCDazlQ6ExA/AdaiSMFVgRkuHwxMKgCnuC4A3L1Hd@YLyyMGTR@xg8am154ooCfOa8Ix8HpY50hpe0YrMu1XKGgTxoofSFALZYFYcxs54wVM6znWJbuMqff3wDHoY4nKQ3khC0LWyImfea4Vu/M7BkbwiM8tFlW8VvymAnhAQAZTbukQAG4INRnDKOazXBFq2NNDTYds7WO8EInNLrmYAhj8JkTBBA6us7g/tAL4hvRa3Kzw4SnQW7XfKzrwYWYsBsr5UVxXxQf6BO9XnWN4ouql6lU1Hj8iSuWxTEMy7o3MA5m0HLZc@hJujtPixNZvM/kdmyA6ySWM0YBxhs3gOMva43WTk6rlzL57F//1o//7k9@fVBTm5n9jLS98@ihM2Fvizh3hPxExcs5c52VOHuYrwDpA/aYEQfsc8kyyUtauZQvlbNaKV0ql3J5tZDPp1UtDcJmsQzSRkYtqYVSvqymS7kycCm5Mvjmy0Wfx1YCplrZqgBYu4vfPt8mkUsegmzFVzjZm4SeZDE9tE@ZaEAcUUD5dkKn1rfMGgywTM2wbJEBRJ11Wez@/f3M/fuieBctuENkPyOKPbTkS5lM8a4oGuSzX0KOS3R4nBJqkRQn3JLJ3IUamHIA@AEGURyi5aCAE3eiaKJlf@/@fUynjxYN40OwE@7DLVZgKUIwGy3A@hOA1yE0CLbH08lRRg/Qgkmiz33usw9@ovhxkB30ecqDcQAPgpLu7YniIbfs7aHPPhU7zzP6NbTs0SWKLliga4jiAAwDFzqlKHbAiB1EFLtg6s51cMPvzKOOfnuii@KcowcRJIozCq13T0SxHbhjMp/6uckjditkUXmpd8lSxp8oakGmMVg2tGRFMRdaclC2Bw8@1YeTnjHg19zl7y6U9MGDrG7Opgf3Ox9/3BkMOu587@Djp@i1v/8AuJX51O0MOn7EThsuB2LtP9D0k9H86gWlPmy3K7q10utr7XZOt694tedtA3MIsV5DzvxrgAmN2vvgtf@gvauvWqEmgG2kDSN4d/C6O4L3Xb3DvYKLvOg963TEKjZ/RWkmBJQncKkZu@MJ0Fo7PdK7rlNF@6zGMmlkaeaNQqZVJQ82ArkgU71E/34CnzpOKyXP541ZLdOqzWpFjW9x6ifE5kzLm2J6Y7SjlvOVDX1H1XKpWQUVZzj9OItL6g5LqHe23rDE4@SOBjKC2NzZkcSG2trR1FKlUHyxNRXFZAWfO9li5U0iE88who9ko9jaKeYjMYrFlK5olWIRODXAyQQG/A7O9bQTiTNDP0kmMbc08wBFoLKyOZXTrPYTs/SsxvPF5snqrKZWuW5qlrkGrIcfQph2J47LQQ4A3GwnU8FtDQlRLZdEyICiJJLJkOgpYFrsP/3s68cnx8efE0tY9ydFnrgGUq@qb/34wb58eBTY8BMG8n3kVB1X3keqteTDWdbA6RhkFPkBDLIg7wVueEDRdSz5gPbtAbsbeARalGRfnbB8/GAJzrOhc8ZTRv0OVdJJaXcNhl94MHtMr9XBpPdYgnLF9OQZDe/ter3Wro1IBQIUMYj1NUafP1iAOfR43kOtExT9HA/t@R7tWuay2qnNYjOA064xSX05cnovtVS32sMPO9yt3cXI1Ta8O1WjZriu44ogbYvV/o5dm9qe3jeeGC7qUzk82gRmA0/yJfrMSG6y5gGG3kdJ5lKqu8xe5OzxdJTQpXonueyEE36hAyIn8fWg0Od0uLRdE8XLar/GEi8g6Guwu5ss0ZPvJndyVcDTXdZOglPmZf9ln2mskKuSJJJAWNCVCD9Ybp0la/WvwYvDPqlUIDd@RZ8AVEwMAJs98oDQY/Oy2q1ZLCGxGUsSknLVQa2B0S/wsS2JYkuSGhctoS5Jnwl16K/VeUyvedMOfROIZTqqlilUZ@CmFnPVIVSv/mJWdWvjqWtULbD684T8HK1eBaQC7gDMm4vEu1/6RnJbyte4W5VAXSAD0JbbtVnVRi2j0DBq2Rp4pBq5TBpkfHgU0zDma4W0Wkhn07m0VERXGPDT@TQ4ggwErEfCSoiMienMLCOradVQ04nMS7P3Mpk@SQBLQ0hjyfTEObCnIwYuUFXYNskKb0BPStuyQDbrOUzflqixAsmoYsEA60M2NtNDBPXU0C2KkUxKLLuVsDYTGGbzeDo@aLQqlYPZ@OvglZBe7xRSxUzqTTJZTWwka57xWqhXhTqSFyr1eANarj@FyrzpqAG1DCa1qFUajQ4WsZhJZzNZKJ3Zvhhsi3Wxlc5sFFSooktGZINxuhGdVUSOZ@E2biNvbhlQdWpZqwoyTfFlS5pUVvJb@QyfZuQxhbFP3hCTLNEUgzPjiXi8qMXjyXgVlzg2RH9GG2ga0bM4UNf4HXVHBGZMrIhlDQMsSCMdC84EuQN27FJAfpHlQPQ9Fy7PL7frwleEZ3jYc1t7gb/ii0d7R/j7CjiVwVp68ej50fOj@wJTaBcpMJ/VjapcbVfBIsn1XSFWYQwoadNXaKVsMPah@1NT2/UX/N3EEwwAVyDN4Q3Won1jholyHfsUlSXssDiUQXdHDU3LthpaEcY@oKZBUE1Tq6giKoYnJOS6QkfhcsUsHYUTYrNzyOx2ity/xuZzPSUFMwN32O4gtcmP9pTFbYxX8OPx9bhNjHTaPo0x3AX/onpaPcmUtwVCbuzKdvnqXm1v8HSvysRssShW9/bbYBQTLFYV8z7Qau5B/Gn8OH4Y307WxVKBXMu7OJO@euqiDtzVyYnqHz8qZtpiNcbaYt4/5xc5o5QTt8tNAXfXx2PncRaLX8JvkcUXb4IjTAWAcZLZfgH0MBZmJxkLktDa4gvmVU8kNbMNTWaXznFq/Bwni4UnOXEZ2l9ByuYKLFkOlne@Et@NxXEVpeJ5bxdHBH3oalusx1hGlU6qsW0mlgK8vMmcVMViwbeVxZxfwKSfBEie2KKDE3Zfe6lBZ4rZTuAA0ibOBMJgn8/jokVMeTn2vtBK2UeHR/Y9937krNcLzADkAA@uVSsv2hsnKnSirJg9ScfYboyOO4hlSF/jDoDwE6ZWXyDimfj83tEjMYfIArkNnBJQKJ5rSLS5cbHh4CoVC3dPvrU/@Tpj43g2h7sPa7FZLefv3FfrdUnd1lCvXpFVYMjsqwUpc1HnRKFOHgUNfN790g9ys@0S2LWMCnZNy6e0el3d0lgyNn735e@jhqTzg0/3HrI4rm383Z/8SCv@3Z/8K9oPGL@k9Q4tW4xBSDSqhWLs/Hx8fn4JF/fLx1qxa9sgWlCZilouF7fkKqsour5VTOW0XbuqxPwCFNVkzJNi/p7XbCEvJRKqArnaypYySfC78ENqmRLYglU/HlwsQEVBAQ6emnlN3d3egfLtZHNadQPamxqeG2bhb9vwyjEhVnr08oIxsHTrvcHA1MikKKzyVmLbb6Vt9hbX3N5KG@xlrY6bOVQ8bRysSW3h6UtcmY3XU8pWnIGIyeqNy@plK0WLWiCqvzCMLbt5BRvNDTyAs@y0ZcPP2PLoh5ECBw@sgc3YeuWJia2kovR64vX@vW2wfB0azJayOBPNtoKlKv6TpGby3S/9hqYV/u5Pfu2ifdH@XAMxvVwuqFrsZz/bntpTz@jVfwYAbtCOE4jaxG2jGhs0hCI647pbTT9WaJC7ohCb2iiO8PCBwI4iOgNWzhzYRo8EduEU2U@q3DZX0NhLULAtVJ6RJnGGFKIlq4IQ8P1cXHEH3TTBYFuocLjRSgrnwlfRC7gbBiJPVfjqAhQ4jICfcbptz5q6YzrAlKB4aivN7kAUSOGrqPxyg5R@@EOjpFaZsnU9Ks@yR1gjVpWNDM9DVZowqgtfhSi@VnZrzsY66qfBkKYNY7GMQSif5NFrQNotSNviEdrkmqDS8wBpxnPHI9kg0ghfBe6MsGAC08bMbQhQBfr1VUAAlCHhAzZbbJtlk@zcTKWqCz2dl3iQAjWJ6oFuDAGjIbQe6mIJIlcxHDiBKIXfAcZ24dcw8MwRxwAIh8H3XdRAGMPoZEM@mJTXvDcogEWK4hJUNHbnziJXtZrZSzIqEcI/Mcc41Uj1YK/OKwALBNmPehUxzVADajVwDZsdYDxF2YVWJ3HVp9VIVCai9VIQ4P/ejRZb5JWqIo8qFsCvL94ruoAyiIxo53XYZds1pmrFJAsz34W8dylTpKEglM6bs49k7fPA8xJy@LNY8JUtIFrH0elbv91eVY7CQHaZ4ieOUEUeJwa@UhOuBA@J3@EkiB3GgqKYFoXumy7IjbQhJNC/mciqSYy20FdK@SA6ruUYnjjIJ/FFsTA0g7eOeiT9dDZI/1XXgQr1xo5NiidJMRYe94AWATTK19nHsz21z/CTeH7dUORojjzS14ctH3NMijQd1DBEcXE/Rsc19JMAN2lmDGTWHfWYVmYJamikW9AOwSUpEmW4A@IH4rhjGSPI0jPDoGOEXkVRBsCSTjukYPGRCe1qeN@EEcj2lHscwcqZeWIqx6ibWnL6eNqQq6uJIReL3Y9v/fCVGVqOc8Is88Tgs/KJJWU/HgMBDGSINGB2cQNiK7irSMumcR5ITfNQcBfhVeTGUjoSdyMxT15/Z9WNRBtr9ILGGxNqxTJOdTuCX7ouBH/mwZt7gbowUnoFdjkkuYavKKgWRxUgoQYswVd8ViOdWzKu9owTYkwMFIahURi7xinDOQQBxxggmt1A9Q72YijtV2kAoL4HPQv1iE7cCiqMgpy4vUQXup5P4G32EctqAgbk2tx8zWsAA6u@tgwd/CAqlsOb9KBiZFriQLoCvXPUAz9UVeI3P4wftG40k47XRfNmGz44HHQorRrj3SKw5CMW7B3YnqnoG@BZgByuyMlGQkwB2JSYFDnoMP7V6Ly1C0RLKuw6pDRDCD6qAQqxCjqSHFQUGfl2nQAed3WPf@DE1zJ6dnYmk@rbqWvKhoffc/McW7eU8cAE1ttRJsZo7H852@wq4wDuwiTxzzjK4@F4Z4bcba18Z87fgtD3av7OrES878VxcDzFz5UNRqQmD/XTedSg7pv0qcNuwt8oxtuf1kqfB@2vgu1PKsUvEQhIbQBmlp6nu2kAlu50T9L9s17V9zilDgnAoRaNwBEVUruBZeQFJnPcD0M4E6SjoVfHOqE1c4Ak8gnzRdK8hEHIeWD17WNzBpFs44ztua4@T5B/EkNjA07Mie1hcxj2yQeMqPz9nGtHNmeNeWsp@iyMDoNauGPERR14wvnNQLmqbPSfcf8Z@M@4/2yRaJBsY9biLBk6XWJxsNWj6tQgJIKZB2EuuVrphQ9BBn4cRCpyw5DzJbdLuLs1ih3gm9ugHmtBw4A2MQaEGwml8aLZaLZszzjbaqWUATR2kRABNQ6gGy3C6VkvNCP2rVNr7HhLTjZqzIVRyc83OnWHfmvgbQXLGFYQNQyOLxOVnA5G/tYWzhD4BQYIyIeBJ7IGe5OEmayGutnJExpOQ1zgmGes4WemRdyX7@W7AbvEUc8RGwXUigBC97BIkE3wYUHP4V/vDKjDZ64DYYKwEn1wcITK9uKtOGDySlfhtKZKlRTJlSQF2QS0I7tau1qUwB@qonHFK1LMS7/@o9nf@ODs96FfrM49NVg@YFSFaFfBbajAQvjdhbDK6rVIvUIOlC3dMlwYuQ44f@qP1pDMlhKIGTwdLIJ3Zk66w0Sk8rtJXj903FW0xUrYFOa1GhRxXuPdkveLAKUc4WE0z482DxqCH58TEICRWRnN8KPNotFmtRonHGy2JtpZJJMzyuSMR@GhZ2sy2fKjgfR0GAwvWD0t4E5xn6wI8FQ@jAIbNBaZp58auAHhFSoCxUUaP80FzaFW4LchZLGxnXVbK1NvRDIdIVpXAGBDvAagxz8EXhGuEjxVCm0hjeKoDGgUt/nNgNMKaGBEgqtcWXYibGQkAwPDL6ZoHIC@K6YagqjSRDv@MvwW04FjcKvXHTPLIdVlx0z6yu8fxLGFmI100Aj3oWZySJBRknlu@1pmozxHjO1NQcABrq5z5rDECmYb3JWpH1XpWE5HGem4kQg/D8xd5fE8GcgPuFTFdsfORJ84uVyFC00mNbtV6XOZwRzYDn5VLKIwH3i9nmN4dnwCldp1BrbpGWmGukxPDF/sMPxPeAhRPtk3Op4g@FvauBiLoHm7Qla33TZtc9JuJ3CnaLIS7penjaPYPONxAeVfMEXiA3nygR6NE07nldGdJG@HiV9/8KMdm92TxNHY90QdH3sMaFgX@H/wHQIHwzxnITmSZnlkpTuTBH0HZeiMnAFwfVNPxrlm4Qr4wwVszJA@HlNe0kxHkbYS@QYI9ZJEN60n/ahf@@Co7GtaQk@G8bVlAEvISDP3Ko4Rs@6K5Nprk@PRgvSefXh@n0Xz@@z/7e7799rIlT3/xk@h2GRwh3bbJoEkJmZiwCQ@h0AukORkCeNp7Db0xNget/nhSTKfe@8f@wK7/@8j7Kvcd7h/7VOcrW@V1K22jSEzZ/fsZ/OZwd0tqVQqlUolqVQ1H19ehU/iLEvzqiR@X9WP8wkEypig8fhuNNB0klvtKXRSqMSfoVdJgXuj2GZDvTYwrVHWms7udYg/3PgtorcY8fe30X9@B5ri9ft2n0/DXh2OSd5cwOY1z4EgI3PinKfsDQeyZ7q6mLW371kX5UUM3h2oEKTGsuDqwSk2DcwBLbujeAPZAL6D52EbN8X3bDBXlcQZOA2vXPV55fYu2m62g64/Dtp5ndO14JoWH9CCjeXV/RoOQcdCry9rvTzNXU6cStM4iC6ZKrewjO9eOc7tbCVZwph7eKecMWzcTj@kT4lmbPFVZbea1gFLSzlsx16F2P4cjAdjibvQlSiAWo7K/CM9CZcddxOE6CCzZ9lNqnXmic@DfNyke8wIcV4v3WS4RTcQ4Sxrug@/j0R3t5Q61ypUNb2cSUccmt3j4bwet7jC8KQcRt2PJe9iunvznMVqAiwRYVvfN4VMQYaZTKuVtyHKl7k91u9NyQR843263i2zSnOGQI1LsqQbhbzcZv3CyWBl3KBfbDi9p18APAtGTWEo0zbsaenAuopTLvyBpbXoL6SkExSLikJyjYaVK2OeKfuXb3GdrVvrbE3V2UrVGY@AdJVWpkwrVaXuBXTPvC7oBp3RLdIZSVg70888sU3/en1/iN2KL0vhUiV01dLVUoUE8lKwVKnnSSgvtZcq2/wQLVUO@eHzUuWv9JCMraWvSxUzLJBhSK/88BLftQjHe2upspV3vmVG/ucgMvV6S5W4TynPj/LKFCFSoN2kNeKIrdfXzRwNA5rYWKl0FTgmcrF84n0Yl/8v0X8SQ4yjCyERe5yPOLNaVuXUpGHNGFIPTRsmesWMkVzRs3l9f4fNzOIsqGaZ1nh2GQZPanhuKS2MBDGk8okG/RKCkJuV2Rgpaya7Jzq6duJQ7uR0/Uw9j/WBdp7TjynzSVIJB47T5U1/pUFIB94PTxS@Dc8pdEx1jBHOZJ0ZaIGoPy/NaRT6Oo2L7n27h3ivO52JsC2YLNJLDNaS6aTD8eEcKhv0B2km4VRcdwjtMrwpJ4MS3DtRjKWCHpm3JPNn3TIIBnvwO/OaY5UDaikRhMTj0omMsnheYFmMpETWWZqqDD5CwZI5NMKD1mcOyretHzmfiBuX54rbpiFTVqpkyZUWk1TYgwuyS38ktceL1zock33f8tWUvMFeSx4ArJJxLSJf@9@hv/dFfzcKtSHCRAWzFOvZU@m0ej13lp3AvJtUO92BSHTVtjNTOYprSEhOqwNLM5/Ha1MqPkw@RMmXSmPoE9q@IVu8JriDbpNrC4EFLWF4lf74eYU@fl65nVDTGkn3yjNKi4eaNBxpeIxp0rT5uErDZ3UxUnh/2@9@dwcP0x1sdx7gcQOGEySXUT687LGVSzK2SWzLF4jUckWJIOfj0ribk48k7vnoNj62pQ/7zYPt/b3djzTpPn361NFz9DjBD6MWe63xPC6Q2WY9ng9mLFtWXETOwmE3tuOj8/5w9OBTLzslS0RYkzLgUy2G/fQYd7Qss@T5xNilcpLXoqiG9TkZBn5KKkHV8TFlh5quIyJIMMo/8jUQo94SvV1erTkcI6rZ7PkXQbPJ05cJCq5nMXSNORF3/p57ULyMhhz8WgKcXWcy7AtEbe@rD69rR@rodV3tvNv6q/q4/059qO0dwQnE23ebu40tRf/X9w7rKpMyyEMwSCwoia7bQStAiF@1Uio9UQx5qz8Yi9zJbzny/dC/UK/7rQDHVC8i/@Llubx4vWC0IaXqtBwdYw8z5OCfF@EI9hYcrZKWsVBu2nxFE5csFOU9pTXtBda8F/122AkpbwZr30EYROZWn@qG1IMkb83FdleUJASmZNMhDjgLC6xrKu5TfpzdEBhf7K9AYuSQSJZtT2nCxf@@m4JH9YM3hwr@RLb297YbR439vUO1s39Ar28/NvZeET0bh0cHjc13SOKMb/a3GzuNrRp/EARKnoKjj18uo9FcFDxkZ6q0PuPk2xtQ98dv6V1vaPDq2ufLqpFauuxB@oR@N/wtaC@tZy4jqC@4IMtHBSq/WDt49Z7mfBX8ihNOcxTM9gfZdxEHS10sqRdcGw2WDRpv63q40rRXKDt8HnExVoiXFKyzA5A8P7vKAGcjnnYYqOwWbFSw9y1@QngsG9BU0QOCDVDGYKWqOM7Z0pL7gkFuUG2tbh9uXaU2MSLULyj60piarGeYYtpWBkBxjaTRw35QeT3@QHxPH1Z0taOhZFCP4w@SQT2RD1BFG7AdUas6x@Vo/xLiWa3Jh18uBjt8LKyexh82fV7FPtM4Sb9xl/oqjhMJryldjmYnuzwccdePWmHIRSLOj0hv3a4MjEBijJJMlKNEtm2jnFkSNh0cNWizN4ndjVTiBtgJ@Z1RpPJVx1NHMA4KeqHEETzr@j0xgUpMd5j31DO4qKrqu/BhHH@PL@YM@syAiP2ZxiMut621wuC@5ajk5lSNvraR5Bi4xgTtLgQ2pxD4I2AIUCG10mnxTMX3hwGm39GsnI/6xJHYt/3dzk/s3L5sBakC2mor/0v422@OJrKbWicZO0XGjrrot2BIaiUfZXb6QxrjLFY5YhmkYOu8PxiF0of5dAv4xImnOcqNiY1q@7m6kaoNdJissdfvWZWeEhffUuspMeV9amWOl7PzWHwloayJ82kSFrs7oOOf9q8C6@zMxSHSdYDtF1KE@awcm5/jEWMi@mcmkR2/K0TAfVbd2N78VPj9ZxdhcEUsSBRqY3SI/4kxURcNDz7nY4PFIfQuPdJM@MLo8hSltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPQ1rXvWyux2libjz9HZeWJr/zx69fq1KqAMmkQ5dH5/lEurnq2FTpcpkTpU1ALNlJyJKsz5svLsOM5fVLXFRCL8DjUg9yBOv2ieCAWoSY1p1edkiy6BjNurtj@I7aYIuKJMA9LiDZ/VH8Kb9ZXd5wiolBibLImTci2jWQy45jmaXwfDUFbns@OJLf9wf3bC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7fC8u2wZFqyYN0f7O9zwMrk9ofAUtvd2wHLJDkNLeb0mDndxVxsTTu/xp@n@o7HHoHB3IsdlBioVdtlj4@ojZP0vBRwbDCJQnR4tF0/OFBZWZ9QWZJ7WDK0tRgE7AfqbWJtG/ZY2Hmx0hQvlmPlyXxJWbSZf/MG80zi3SIqtA7ianrEwiJxxd4Jb0Tq6ZmFVQi2vmeBaCiXxu6LkUHRsQb8jdaAhGzSaVYDMzObmZPJJ4xsI3BNN1d0Y9uGny2sZe5G5OPh2AZk2wT5Z7hZMrv/Poh@XDH1iIIFb1NocJs0aZpvaJ1wSBUPKKPnpXtwTreYLoWRvSjYOUM7GH6V0hr2n2coZiRRwkUXtsS6Vo41aqIfLxo1hw0SMQ34sPTUiWLRTAlGxPOXF3aHOsmkl09PQaRkIhbuS5srqPjJNz2FMTXiebIaK@T2WFtkbI4NlifYndWw12/P9BC20GuT4mGyKpK2c6sq/GOqklkiVZOh@czGmESCvLa6@vgu2JOtMMULfxa2zCGT8nN0MaD1fQIyGke8vU@c29hzTXrCAHNIJ6b1ZsBMFCRVZ8ackmo7T0Y2foSL7AsRMgg0gPDCk7U66mYCt9nQZUayoXOWqTZYQzhuqIyaKep/m18dBPKd9T34/vpksCETTAe/wSr/TX8YBcmtPMtzjvUJHgfS34LhsMfZ5D7TBaDk@RrT3Mt2fNtODF6lVUjk8za7JR19O0nMbl2z18CV8Paih4ji2N1bn9zeK5TX7abuNHbr6hH7Ge2k9iKzw6xjyZ4HYW8eAiyDeV8C0wff4XsYVeh/wsE1IIlMfJsvz7Rx7sSNKUJa8zGHntJmoVq2lid7vxO1/B58rbjZh5HKuj9QQd6Fre/vOLN21kvrqfKEXDTo5amUmy14WS5K37ChC0hpENKb@G5NWLipYSwlcb3mrA/7KBxsBTeye8aWk36x/Ky09jzDreu5I/fi@PmJ@6hVzSqafP3eRXQ5vG5/PuufX3VUVw1@Ob1pjX/7VanVJ@ox1bXyg7h7Lq9Vi@xf9yn9faael5hzNYI/8lV5RLj2JPSvUksqWYevP1AOP/CiuYIbEhNcqh5dGC7EFbtR9eJ47aTaq5bWL457J@u45Ddaro6Wy8t5fPiBZlGSMXIyfzw6wZxq77oGvSsFl6ocYlZfDVF8NYS@vPGHYX@3tvcqtRsHBQBbYNrWmzfUJZr4AqzZcPfE6wXXeb1N5ipwbAYKUmaBbwWV4RKA95OxHdMOCTPqFZe02eiG/46dzELJuxyM@pxi/GCCtdTX8GtmwVxjKvGOAmU5Do23TNwvIDhJnjwOhuTrWKyoC2VR18q4O@lYII5RksVh9lM2izuFQFTf5To@yURe4LfOgUSX1OqvXEy9eKHwRqwWebyLB1MOf8gXJkoneMQBCP0M@LQBVbDmHvG1jww1H@9lPMgX3qMa8T0ZNpDPsKaIFJh/qy98v4nLvyACCOEXROfy9Ban1rxIkZS7g7y5ACdz6YU/jhlwrVI6ZQGNBWypr5oAZ0txphGq1WSi7wvXIKfQiv7pFhTK/DbVjDi/I9mZJHxOrd8i0JK7lJM28NNNiuWtYgVTzGS2SLFwJzWw00XLozcBDaux2gq6XUJaaLGQkAOPfL9X178c1x8do86TGHlJL0ylF1LpnqQLUkkujyb4JFPFzpTNfUnyfVPZJJs7VVdVsfLiUU@3PFJJkrzr8/JG3qjfDJPMG3FXClfGCS9SCQUr5acZvS8pD1JlYgaP048lXfP3iu75GMtU3pfp@vGb0R0UsPGstjWZ4FKvF3Z/zOjI6zoFbJYlaiolxTmmpjKDqqrvYGpxQhoc9vl52G5UEyjLZSNxeMxkN168zHpayfgxP4mG3GKcGlgzxohFJa5zmQl3wxcWqR5OfmCBYJhgNGVG7oYpPNaFxxZY5HpgqpVbkFMDnJo2OcSruBf5FX/MYE8jZ/LlZicuCOY30ni53ZwmEAvdB9nZZEpLE1wXkY@6UXNmkaTu8STE2UJiz9oFjusM5A52B9vgD2I5YQsKIymm6B6naEonGcqGfW/rQiR@y/y9@Cjzyicde9ANblQNywyfb2FlUhfcR0E0iuBtix0BRZeDQRenjqzwXfMVah3BYGUVxy0JRGtm9zINWPZIfhdP@kI6FfLUPiBfw0AkSYguz85wmQw3YPvXEK3YcQlHXqbWG8uGBo2ZxytyzTxQcL7BArgbntlISM/J6AGlo4HfCrwM6WgRaT8ZaWon1KFoeT8d90bg1I2mtEom8y@XYevz1iuc5z4tlx6XLZJd6ePgkvf4SXLBiohkElbgl3G1/CSTsc6GW3I2XABAV@1ion9PvBlcBb1ekKnRjMEZI1Jao2B4FbS9TOYgiA@BAResjJNJ3MPuXw5bsrlDSpdPzIhbwpErx2HEYfjF/CzHxS0@K3MzOLRKTpupq6/CNghobpx0@jgd5gMLuAkQeqDQRTAiojxyVBolPnvWuLDucoGNKKIG/JxYZxMxGXr9UdiinuGdrEyXQMkxSFJZrz2BCdXX6vq4HOzNQgDXYxIKGATMUdI8HDL60Py7cFC6YeaM3Tc9UyTp1@exQsM9GIYkfRMCc69wMQt36uCj141Ddbi/c/ShdlBX9Pz2YP99Y7u@rTY/8hk3DsrZA7J6vb9L0iU@TZdT8336kK0dUsksJ2Rqex9V/W9vD@qHh2r/QDXevN1tEDQCf1DbO2rUD13V2NvafbfNp@8EQe3tH6ndxpvGEWU72ne5VlMsk5RT@zvqTf1g6zW91jYbu42jj1zjTuNoD5XhVL@m3tYOjhpb73ZrB@rtu4O3@4d1hYZlthuHW7u1xpv6tkf1U52q/r6@d6QOX9d2dycauv9hr36g2EjAauVmnbCsbdISFjVxO7cbB/WtIzQoedoi4hGCu646fFvfauCh/rc6Nad28NHVQA/r//KOMlGi2q69qb2ixmXyd1CF@mXr3UEdHpRAicN3m4dHjaN3R3X1an9/m2l9WD9439iqH66rzO7@IRPs3WHdVYiCyVUTDKIWpdPz5rvDBtOtsXdEc8a7t7B3cKiTPxBhCMsaFd1mAsMMAq0lIu0ffARU0IE7wFUfXtfp@wFoytSqgQqwqNg6srNRhUTEI7uZaq/@arfxqr63VUfyPsB8aBzWHeqwxiEyNGCQ8ZFYhyp9x61GPxFe8kjMmjGc63J3qsaOqm2/bwBznZs44LChuYXJtvVa09yDB2RrEyXsY8/Av7A3VjrTn64C@Pyc3pGZvUcTe0za2t@u04ysnV1lk4R3NOs8m3ClZKfRTBMn0mvKZU07OL08a4a9Th93TONisvFxEZ25iO3kICzOp8yciGd6f4UL5HLN5vtakxa6h82m496nZAqNu0robfB5uRzdRkS/wMobGz@VitD9RYpQGz/og0421MMBBHIK9X8Q0zf/InBUsdgOdDFc3gdgs3UUybHJOY5SSDTyZUfE80mq5J0Jfg81O3DBvAHvtZrYJ4VlJGfqR/Sn9zV5kcnB@kDSWba7ikUsYhmN8LfAVCOVsEsE/qM9EoQdrtKLguDzWb5kV4c1v3fW77fzjmPKcN4RrQPP8s4dxU@Ds4nihcnyjCwfO@vAEZFZd7MKE58/a5Ip3S/ekFuWx5/miH8cg434fMCuKVfFm9V60zL/gxSHRZKrtGsLXK/gTobO96b2t8YHrOZKK0/WJ76/jr/L2IK9ILwD04R3zOVO@Of1iWSgAca@OIgkofaQUSxaZYy9SZz5mjKeI9N12IblD83V5wHP60QSUmQv/a5dJ2bjYXhjY09y@NVB7c3mu50dEp3A9smz1adr65nY7dbfXPn9iHrYgS97HRvQPE56GidZo2SLFB8eKZb/9IT9mYGLRWSE53zTafwRfh5iu420JRMEGZobIbhVDyZ62QB0yCp2wPEgY/h15sjUDJBPNdVBay78G1bxfdKVmAe0MUt3zL12gz@AHQ9/M8TjBmkG0izGLo2Jc2l1wXIvu2NMRXlxw457kMXLGj4WN24xDXiri@1ncbuW3zRvW70YiSkjxit3O5ckJB5MYqGMXUVPRvZb9jOiN4DZexh9@ZvmN3r8qB3csbs7PxrVRodExp24JPapk81o3ehjDfkEkUzgVM3U9EJhl9/RSPHY09vJsWMQazQwKgjLAxvfNOD12I/IZJVsAftyyVFfhFPhvANw1jXH6nfi3FnN0VDWjf8Q/W68UiiBFTs5Eapdx3VkTJaPsR8LQ84Umf4UPRj@P5EmM@C/oBUnQU@oZTkBvBclGarQipavTJTw2hw0WKcbCTXtTx8TMN/sjjmPG6ZPb27kfg2RQPfO2Hz4yG4PO/kZBACTY2PDHr@xSdq5T0unl1lHF8c5Sa91McgrPVeYqWIKbmHtxGW1yzVnK3hxlCN7TVaFu1RUvZSF2ymPeloyTSzl1cMoK@Ac4/@j@Ig3QOIBz1x6Llark5xV0qPMyAHtasmacNqxxyRSS7/demr3SFkuMlOyX598GUIR6A3gM91ODunSV2Kem/a4yDOxOmIveHDTjmUyJh/tsu6UDTG7AeA8bPNmCKK@jK4xQXQFOrvqS6Cp/EM2FEElidVh4mcQ4tbxiLQ8rV7H2PPOJDg0xv5dTyIEBLKrZXJ44uBDY2hfl/fUG39MKHfv12xhseKjw74L20VUJtsSujwi3LT6/SGpjj7aTTi64djx1Ae96RD0osuh9l9I81k41DsSRumnaqA2yeqdpxlxzc@oReEItxXaHvMHN@kigIWouCe5KaypPDGv4dENs@kY3iyXVf5FkvKCaMJuSZmIL9Sa@vpVcglBtcvQgCkYRvHigm02uR6cO8TD77o//Iy5HypQrx20Y8@kFkjeC5ROavTYx2NrJE0f9CPe0aCuwA5ITImybKTFhqo0Rz/V7KTtmrKJd0z4LuWWfH89MZMaaymqKGFcXTsx31qBOhNUWtGuQWNnoeWVVUZl1oLr262LMfYWmj62VtlPvVikVESJqD40qiOeRG7GTx/xpDf5qw8jjB76gjNurYICYeisOFedlnOMH2wKPoTBsG3viZIm0/YH2H7jpU@/x7xotg6127@WP4qCMa0AWsXwpsgwmvm/9M97za1@1z8L@6FP6zT41b8RiYfHMT@iw86G/euIgzdJREorU3ucPIt/GXHDhvf4XHLdcs0VjYJB3jZTGA3HtXNxE8E75zACTCLOMn8PJn2kxWWerCaFMun7p2yPV3bWby37uDyrsJzoA4AWcBsTFhRyh3TEF5Osy6frUxlO52WwcDxVBeU7t1jspTB@TiTiY5gUxgaZKbMEuxFYmd2K8XH7xm2zD8IhHC0F2wECDUV5/uz6CONNUuRHWApUVPlZySoqpyg38EOIh/Ht5F55@k/GnhD4E@iXH8/illmMwCKuY7wtRbJe0V5GCRc2DwxZRrMkJikWnoU96/ohR/W4mYSaTh7fRg22/CGlSLvZm@JKjMg8LXwQYzDfJJHTHDuYVJbUksN@O6CC1Eb50u0MG9xlP8uDH4e4snMGwbSlIectpG8jVYuohDDJE@a1NsriU/nuEbOyct9emyBgdZbJmRWwO581mgvfQAllfsWxVn9Iwjg7QT1t6rEUjfqDpXtS71bZMdMz2yxatxznTkNgYbYqTZaP2kza6hiP4/XMJD4TTJOmGFuaEQ9h@crPMZtPEvGm2sR4qzbHd9DhNpoldlPxpBL3d1vGPibFK1j0mokmHlKMO5yUrsffj5vU8ObtEkTDlOVVkyVGEyKjOZZHC9QEmWIq3Z9CzH0a9wl6tIlyqLdNtLP751aiThrJGZenJinl5BL0hON2XNokuTTowPgCbuJEw42FVKxw3rhjPsorF07hZBgJAhBacVBI9qFkBzfprAk@4ugAnXwT1kJlSCJ62rAtHGKn/zHB2Cu/3tzRFg/NcaF8si6QbmJItKrgXPMgmfvm9HrcvGEoU6SgIT6DFHGLpmTT@f1b9WfbQvkIgpTmZG3pW3LRGEctEzb0x05q3kAHTqrSJVMjKj0QmiwaaCzQKuWsG8hyFdpfOBSOh3WDHka0gJDPefws6xJw571WiqmNIjftMbI4mtwy2hxV2JAiCUPJO8ivh6KourxwJQCBYEzlq2WCALemjD0OBdj1js15KUR1H1HBahnDkj6yV9TEznNGOoiqMzxZtXKUZuV4bsMozARCisXsPAkipLPMzpJAoYluJi5Wjqez25PkIIXY8L5QnLpC90qahnHPCQE5zHfJSSTKcVm5Jc3BnPhk1UklxvzNqc9LVmppMpXoE2N4XChPpj4rpVJT1a6spIumShI9HLvWVCKRwrERjqXCn/vHV1Nsl@exTai1yEhpGdo@G2HYaZVJ6zbvl0i94EvZRscw8Oyb4Wb51ZQQKymn7PMdsKslPjKA7/Y/3VpjmWow0bEC2C@dueySlwUha6xZTPVoFla6xtNe7KDArGn7HfX@aGcn5fb1dGwMjS6C4WqpVAITn9rO741tNbaSwn4xnbvYuex2i4PrvwzfnxZZ9gcBhwSomBV0QF1CgyLy@sMziQwBHCgrchf0RVas9S87HTsEA04o0XnUbZJTe0NQPAGFsdHL@yPeAGKQeoL9GQ1E@35W8ei79kXR1FDMMRSVhknwVdacnhF58KED@@z4pIqBQTAbayaat5zqxhfMIIhswp3F7oudL4l5cvZ10O32XfUB4Z/hKWDh22SBnR27QEmy4ISRb/deRuyP1lXBVdi17hUji83rAGcmJhNnwviFh2/8g@CsfjPIZ49/ytK0Qk1eRjOX4Z/aVdmzrKOdxd8DrPAhoX2v3Bf@IN9iOk1mpqlej@DkiTB6XHZnrn1SWRzeE9M0uzs3iDobXY@dNVDTHdYFjC977l5uyS3ZY@JmP92UO6BhSWBonOBz5X4lcNXsnycWr0adzv2kIocBkI79LokokVD@nEDkMwAegXr4ET3hRfuvBRrWOxMORUTBQbCOabmDAk0UyGQetqq/XudrtZpaHCwvq1ptkx4KBVXbrKltfNjcVNv0von3H6orq6vrInO3nS/0cdN8/KY2CQbvcC63zofb9EppVdwbg7U2unixWF101xeb1Rcb61HxuLaJa/309J//9l//89//W7GmX/4HXjb55finOJPnecXF1pfFH76t4/14@2Rp8fR4cXCydLYOLvs7ew3vN0YFPzEf9YanmZzMAtZXtiM162z2PqOLKhM88MIffibpUlG5VlTM6a@RRI5iGZtrBdb3APcoT2kJb4IOTC7lCYkcAR1jO556pxXAAI/mG6Ik4QI7UCkvZytm4x7uYOIM8alKTnviYZ31KsCdlsSTAu7i0oxVCHtR0MMO@BXrvNK8TMan33DU1Pxb/OlNdLbZv1GPPuXVo5J65KpH2Sz/lNee01dnsRjidq5ko@VANutSSnK0ADNDFYWs6PH6gWPtTJA7k1nkkD2AZNxUcGa5BefGqz@@LCMB16KzzAJimyrZIuFDJhTJfVnsfaNu@UI5vmVTV21YUWjqVQxXZp2oxP0LFciPxBAgqflCCFLpU5U46eMbyXgqmi@6rzMcTYgBg6wHr3Z43OMDzUWLPW3znFpLIcwRm8/LV8yN63IZmtFGitSfIMAHKrKcLPFNwqXcUkasvK1WcjPlFrbdPs18YuswDkbGNl0K/a4sJhBrbptwiz19r0UbcsvxisqG8fGKVVV20vZbZawiF5fdUTjQ1xW4dgyoL3Ft32QkoUcZkMARn/2V6RHGGwXGU9REt0iwrLFq99F0GQk9fTWdOtjx5OTIIkLxpzyN7a8TY9sp8i0Rww7CA4xUbMrX8cNupL2uDJnYZ/7wFNEB/Q4HVBvJuRnv5yFG7QTG/U6MtMeQ2eQ8Gc/UlNxg6J9d@K7K7fWPhv64QdMWaT6jludQC@GCCUhg8OmqZzXPICwt0l3CFImbwpZDCF7QHevwaNK32fjOCbrUDAXtdgWDIMVOTMnga6qvJuiYcPV3dIKN8pTwjk8jtYhlyQtLIw0pa1@b4WE2NXQypgZ77MQDJ5sRVOORaXhBF7rERHvBB78kybvwEaDrzupbgPoqwtpz1I/Z6Szo@anJadDNmIv@xXUl8yLGM4eiFGukjIbytJxEvANWpEf@lPYCIXOTcWeUWcjnFz5FOpxbzp5H2Ml3bItf9FUYB6DjAGZ8M0S964UiLCdmqCQGhqcabPlPEDpd/4zwG1/7Y7Dip1z@xwdF5/inT72TR/lPva@ffnMYEy2SzSxbUDl9mG0klh4rNDMW3dSrsUqLjKvBT710hk89JXdYLBIQIsX88U/Fk69FQuhTznEeFT/lhCCpLgMmxfn1FQG@OIVmLo1FMZdZcB45pvPzP5YdRXMr/6IP5YMjv4SFWVTyNj2tc4YdAsX3dH@9lCsnUfHZSunJSvkJrYTOgpvCMLjEfFuILk@DG1IlIixnaer59FuKG1KE@HYT@ev08YbaKWFN5O5JpC8paRGqhznXk4nZisp4whOUn6jM7lJxxcWJ8/g4fMSC31XEciYv@4IS00GL@/KYP6P@BerxI8i1ydshwpGwMhAbEd5CLQCyCb5yG4c6Zrgs8T0nT23BdysDoe4t5qzZotfvFbSy5nhL61CicWum@6z0rDQ5RqeGaGqELmplaumBKm/8@PQ//vv@r7lRbmOl@GFIv6Pcr7m1Zzl5pAd6e2zernIbuRfItvYtNy7SGpgen/7H/6TyG38hOEgZv6A/G6sG1to4t1GocpGvuY01eiivrFC9/@tf/5XasCgrNsRiXWy6ihFbNxTZ8nvMu5SuGmilLEuXErHCF7MAQywMaW1OLzCMull5VuJtupy2qrgKtOcrY4@ip3g2zBqxqZDsZBh7CtKMpEAVFRQEpDGh6CjLdsOYbYB5EzTVzw@9tYhWAD9rc464yth042EEk6FFWRZRB@alRlrPy8NG6cdsbN5RyRqbknWjQmJpp2Xts8frxA5v@8EobKWtJMxwvWj518GpBz70gvYlral6Ubf/y7B4RSx5UV55Vuxgc7/IdtzFAUMqDMbeb6QI6mBAtDBko1NXDakH@hdw4eVytCBS6HfiMykTT5K07EHQkj2sdExiyiJ3/Fw5HkZzvESVzvNfUuAROVMHgrRipX3qUcn9g4rKLscZJR@veR1g85aNY7ULjIJYww5YNnkZbgN2B017vNrwjC8hcSl4XZcsnt9uN32dls8sZE2oNDezcB50B9VsR9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNvBVKIcQOQqHAgg6wLoKRT0v0apa/YD2e1AA3KfqsNXYVl5C1o/PqVX27ylFX5lR9LVVfU49CS0jqiXnG8sam7GwiW6rYqhwGTRypzayYaotM0Oahxz/AIJJuaXRwLUE3h29AEtWS5mirMrvbXF4LE49cB3JnT7YWJXJ1JpdcfnRNDrlBDd0J9XpSGQkIeMGtwEKZ3g/lBkTVhBkNexnx5zeRbPx7aDDchn24ErXd1onzUZmWeleIfROO@C6lIhJov7K2DXZGZo8YdOxiKw5Bm8XGS9YBS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEymZln@q4peLwsh0dvVYCRdCHbKm88vjJ6trTZ88R5WxBt3Y2GBTysAoYnPsEgzXqPC2y8b1azS5l5RNCUE9XCeizwOIADmZd145j3D5fOw@q5ZIGVsoyrGsOoyHF9XYlg0wgDgMPMwKtUfLDbD7/Y@UYDTv51Ha@0v/E38Y/IDOccUfrC@mtfnibeKbKXIjDgSoLZnaKk38MDyqOTrHzBv3OAbxNBLB1FbaninbhAWJ0Puxfnp3b3OFp11ZHNGCI4OyXGiuoV8EocTBmYQVdVG84NKzbF1UD73i6BTDKxZQAnU@A0zDTfit9bWmK0bFEkxA8a@LGKo4QLdNRm52ZO3t9Vd/bnkQsZ4ehY7iebdlKyh17MoMDGcTqtZp7RNTV3i74KqmWSW7KqzILuBLylfk6vI@70i0EoraoYmQ16w2j/DyylJkXE9emSVHqR@A1A2a5dDcpzb1W0woQxAhCvZsUCzE3Ps@xSZbgZHcyxil4OVuxbETfhFHEDuZ0ZVlHW5RyJo4qsJC5BSD2bUpZaUipgh7lxzoHXpbeRjBHuRWNrQFthhyvVIOZOTnMBFvdRuIAG1HHDS3Q/sbelqu26/Rn58O2C0V5s/ZXtDsO8Xw7vmWNb7miGjumC2xvsWxzC5upX3FFiZilpB3GJghC@HYkKmKQeA2oN3Y07WVQH6fG9knCFWBXXyvhZndUDxI4euE9kAW9eI9dcfB1Hf5Wkc2raUkTu1TRw0K2uOYPbIsmC0mtMSQh5T1ArEyCiB21JNy@kDC8WKCz5u3rtYth7MbObJ5OsawsqEht3ykS2dM8eytl5rHFimaLlQr6cR5fMN/O5Y3ToNPXd9Fi5riDNx78Md4o3J85Cv9fMEf9n8MdjzV3PK5A9gh3xG7D@UYnh2Hvz@CY0zHPwc12eBZif6hjvaIRJdcCwAIPGOIOKSWWS2jbLeJE5WcnLE/ORzASWlnFxYA/1PgnuvFPKpC5/Lgd/L/a@MI/uPGruvGrFcw1M3peq3aWu/V/TIsTlTCf/jCze6HuSjbnj7Z0Tbd0rYLZdEY3/19vaeH/UEuf6pY@rcBjghw4iPv6@dwsmkjtcKvRSMwtvIx22pVHHPvZXOlg7dWuZmnx0OleRudVaOvqD@P/TOP/DNKInxCGDmcRsW1ovJaX5alclhfNknc5FC5ZSUukvcYzutVePWEl6xE9QYmQ5o2toV6okELuSmJy2uQl@mMifePJ5744i2zXwTJxcG4toGVFWHaSIS6arw6SubIWzyvb7ANZbR0d7C7/FyHDhf9Z30Ij5NG110G3a2YSewl2FHud0o2xmgPYh3rNkWIVTU5GdqRve8fssnC7VGPHFhPz4uxFghy14fyP1lIX0DesqNzYMiLaeLq8WVXBNNcsL@QLtV0yzW6ybvEf4tLnmkufV9SBXhjcRipfb/hpXkzWaSurq/PmACnl4QcDsORS/jmj6n8D)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/qoycu)

Build: `cd FishChipsAndMushyPeas/fcmp-interpreter/src && javac main/Main.java`.
Run: `java -cp FishChipsAndMushyPeas/fcmp-interpreter/src main/Main polyglot`.

Fish chips code is mixed with starfish (*><>).

First the code `/1997*.;` is used to jump to line 64, column 10 (1 is the layer number for fish chips).
`.` is fork in fish chips, jump in starfish.
In fish chips the next executed instruction after `.` is at column 10, in starfish – at column 11.

Starfish/fish chips code:

```
\ 23nnn;
\ 183nnn;
```

Spaces after `\` fix `octal escape sequences are not allowed` error in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 2):

## 388. Befunge-98 ([zfunge](https://github.com/stasoid/zfunge)), 16436 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7pdlWpWqW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixZ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7P2f3dNPLa1lBwFC77mA6MuyJVxFiTGXM0u3BVB8YrG9aE8NNM88wWMewnDPw1xjbntpTz@jVwZZlzDbO2IHdNXsAgU2cE8M23xou@OUYe2BYF6OLCes6o5Fu9zw2dk17Qr55xp7pYOlPuydM73gTV@9OTMcGrwJjL2xLH3V6OqPgY9fgkYoMQHVPKM6yT4mxJ47rGZCC0zU8z0HHMjjqruk83n360ZXwaoZ9pEOmxpYxu5K8qrJPTcPtXY2hsU@OHz686pplX5Mcmz28niU1x3anE@dgchV@nu0ODFtnmlyWtaueBUDmxLBKmVLmqlcR6tOYmN2ldMDjoelC7ep@LbKubkNtYV1uMWM0nsyZxOtft6ywbj2me2zqTXWLwtnTUcdwg4DeRHcnpj1gZ@ZkyCZD0wvjUWhvrHcNqWdY5sicGD1mmRDJ6ftQALTdYyfG/Mxxocp9mI5tzSGi0TX7JkYJ8gEA8UpMhgaHM9LnUMn2BBoH05kH2bCMAFpSiEH4B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjkrWd6escCoJ056xl9fWpN0qwDfoBkcj8bGrbfmAGcDCCOHZ6r11PKmrFo83qvxzLQjiEfJwYzAWuUrQrLZsGdOS5gDUIFOfKBUbvmZTRmUGdQRX2nwvKZDPjvhy6YW93yHD8zy1lDTxv6KtUZwn3mOgNXHwE2egbh9JODZ8zrOi7Y4MawvD/dBKarT9j2NovvP30QZ/WwWmS3I4RVVGPnUAWxwJOd6tYUWki0JhyoHzeMLWCVxTfiFRYHtGgZlsuxHHTbEtPygCQ1UwYD9H8tq8JdYFqJ5VToQXmW1YrxNKbVd/WBaRkc0gAhFbHxQxANnpkcy6olHnLgWH0erEsJFlm2xApFVsyzIjzLrKxBigg@x9RyHu4C3ACtDNlR4c7mOKBF24e2iu1tj/X1kWnNfegEvsvyKisCRMizCpC1EkCAdzaLdxZuytbyFYU9GQLGh/opgJcs8wQpkhESJaxGBV7K1pZCVBHJLk/eG2LygD5AXL7EipB8ATCRgywAdrUSJJ/P8IJ4Q8Oy/GhDD6NRbosZuCHnRcBDCWogA7jMIDKLcIMdaJ4GxE0DSqYBcdKAoGgamLOYBIQrgF8BqrPg42uoeyeQEE9H6xHygaoDGBWxjYRMRSQBBKgtloU6K7AcNIYsNoZ8lkH@IS/FAgNaVlJZKcdKRQb4LGcY1I0K@cKWogINVSE/KgKD@lehAaiQJxWwrQJQNZtnQgTZahb9IW4W4gJq1BzEyYEZKk4t4A3xoGWokKQKaWpaedEQIW9aHsqbz1IL1QpQu0XwA7xpkFcNmpMGudVK4I9xS4DDEjZgaLYcETriAWoFmzy0Q0BGHvJDcCEsmLViluNPt8ZDvYMUm8fs9DFqAbtCAdEIUTNYPHjnEJuQlQyAwV4A2degBWSpx8A7FyZvqQCkgeCNnklE2jKBfqkhhoppapCv9fFkgTa1QDkazyfD0E3jbg4QTxMIoDHQu/PQE3pfOvRcuBay6KoRvV0AyuTQ1QPq6kw9awEkNOQ0Sso4Na2FW4nceobe65ve8N0irzlKpGPoE9s8WaSSz6cjSNUjHgX0WHIqZqNhJ6YEQ9ZgiKZFWbQihhk7YQUtZVlVKXsdoz@1B4ZULkXyRz6TqTuBwWWRZpk7u@ZgAOPyAo6apmLSYLlwzlMOrWx2IoSOiF1M0zVhCL/LukNgKkLPModfLi9gZDWEMdc7OLJLwInBSFDGsatvzljnbpdGjkUGs4Sn7tAcB4ErawNHKpcSmZUKkbZBmHtbyoSkGa@W/Nox7UScxZPCpQDjDecuo6M1DGqf4kiFYy82XRhbHeIcFuQzYQejYxKQtjzQw8hrARmFSunqOArjmGTQmBrAMScyg0SAFTScU2RdaWBcSsajwbPjIqcKnE7PcF2GYYG99dI0zHrTjme8mSIvtchXH8ZtA4b3vm5aYQZoHNEnxATAO@5BevPlbPddZ0SDzQiHUctxxmtYFhi0zxDQI@fMWGR9Mabr47EFnBO4G5xxg8yc6cRzE4MeTZVnCCJhPKhwAEhJAcdhukaXcO8XHWJngTdZzmKFafW7WYRyP8JSZaGzALvhYRx7alkV4HWMLsvWlZ5xqqALZ7uW2S3MQ8CIATvlg@jowC9jzikXIaS7mkws3nFQs54zWi4aH18PwqIPTWSOrDN9DrXXh6HVmOkj4OoZss7Qc9kIWgyvQawJkFuwWAes59jxSQjlzAVGFgodloSYZcTJxBwZIAE5EAVrPEeZxtGdctaZQ1MmbOVkEnl4Tq4gShauIoo75CIOvLMAy9ebdhFrmLZpUwsCNslDPt8FUsndhInLmk0dbhd4urEv5clowIDPMWsRIcHjvd3nvrsEEflUw/ZAtPBkZqIMBi1/4PShsZ2ZUHYgWBB1AbtLSEAUhE4zuSsLhHJsQKMTi5msOx4zcIdBCZrnw0wJ2FDntcnegqc1BDGiO3XdOZuNoSbMEYSadJ1@H1rvW2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1Qyth6h5xCB6Y6Xi7mwbRoQxkbBZO/ZL7KBAWgHprWPEio2@UUBxmMqAqFCtzlDa@uAKSxCdzwntAixRYy@48jo3nMMjxqL456EXR8T84wBdQ3oZ/0FMRohgw6t1CbBogeUx@9eCB8TFFYWBpPyW8FHhg1dpwutEjo9VB/W6S7rg6AdYWFR1tC7XWM88duJQ@TMtCM8/@FD5PnJVfKByd5Q2LzHtq@0GggatpwIL4syEGZ97IsiOtJaX5qXiPEIxU5OWaz5teQhxOmV1MVXGGYpB6/ENXkYU5dAAYiIxHSCpASpo9kdIi2cILUhfht6mzu9XnxwiybvjpjUD9PG3KhAdgRZCZ0wH@thSHBb1wHJYwth1ZccMOiSwy2gdW@0ArITZtLqRV1lRZeBKN4GdOTYzgqogMwQLgZZ9qG6oMb4HKmGboWNkbqLt1RHSLAXE0w4kMEYOh47LvQMTnTmNJtAVRZpXb4QngjHiqTM7i8PrTBkxHHAn@AoCBHGlg5tAbsY9lSQrHSgFEDEuJAMNM/hKUYyTL2eYPn5OyPSzxsTjKW2baBwprtzDgSKB8MzJDRnpusCGTzFQYKPQcFgIlM7hTFB7/WQsiI6qN9fTVzGFr037Zizq5J4Fx3l155wqrusj0K4C0wHdKJEvO/Fk1Vyp5gRL1FxxhOFovKnCAEpkAxVnuiDXA@DxEMgNM/ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpNgwIicR2Mfg6hwNXcoPmCjGZ1AvyZblQ1g@JYkeEroRjlBD0VGD90FPgM6IUiZ5XKvo7MLoB4uk2Z7XBQJRBJVzoVpGXYvTMtHBOYlWl6ZJ@G5XTJIkVENS4DBqeQ0SCwh8AMxQRFFcFAUf2xFB@L2uB/xNdxxatNcHEtwViTJzkPmFwaABGXGBObD7JqTts@u3L0bMC4btRo0NuCmgGz2klGJNpi0lIFSQ2CZuBE/EXniPJ9g30gkobwY@JLnBtgmaKm1OjufDF3ocWS/FCAQoFWwsSUHiPXr@al5Mu1drWgbHTGQiL0OmCazOxGrAgz@vDfUbsJqfAmrIPXGEavYeDE@gb7WeMkVK1T0g7mGh@xvzc9KpIYTmAO/ra5EEY/quy0a9N68a/ksATdBZ@fUqAPZP/Ens0JClPZ5gqDTXuupHAh2Bw6HPds9flTz@yL3VDqmXVlysJyubpHzJgYXg7iPD@4f7R79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4Qftm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz8OhrV1ECnBCig1IAM95XWBoeBpguoaN7wyuDMBukUpBkGCUIy6QDFsAMDZh19NeD/Dybvn2LlXc1U2PfHXNmTXUOIHBUDuwgnoyeVxiwwKvT5yMixQUu1LRxsWFhioYM8vMRcs1XM0OsdKTJfHT4cP@oRmD9eTWJgijeBHgp3e3J0OatKYjgq8IA@QNTl6XkRcaRn6a8rkRwt7uE4EXdsjXwAQDKOrLDJGsUFM0bQt73rpaNXKVu2ALIThCu8pVRfqj7ZTMayQcOcV0UeVeNouSxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs1eFCgtDMA4EPCNLnideBK6yAsu0mer/ew/f3wt4x4xkSAKSEHOPIvJlJZnCSi9SCaLe8oeSGiOZcifEsUTmZhUlHiwNiB3PRI@I@H3Z@YkkUnyt5qEsJD67u6B9iAI7E9Z00wGCQ0oi@PI5PZxja/rQRuxHcsZOGwL4nDuMEgQ2Ka1xdwdOPa1GtLREYsaw2VCoL84caOPYawx35LgSLGi4ipfcNRt7wyotFrIIpIIQwRKofDya/1UB3Qtyv384PN9GETUfCYTmjN0AQoicQhdaOpGXMmBSZCQ7OdnZQHDJcNrvT3wkCJrdlhon9CFEXcX3isdiWLKysrwK7P0sXMN46@d@ZWmBS68aYEhgrKDp88eHzzdf7L7WXOi5fNL9lymXADEQXod4IXkIccb9tYt3jWxWAguBn3Dxe4FVGAKAkqwYjT1XCDcMgaReQbWtBq@2Jr42BnacS95tTBn6Cu9tru8CT3BzseD@hFB0O5ZKIy4fMUax3NsP8PJZOxVFAV6@XDakUFoVV53HUsfKBQPBgbLUlQUXQ4OcV7DWxUDMuPNDR6DT24B6zCnGUTdGjkgvNC6N5IGluDgadbKMgdDkIVxcdxwk3LYgqk0Sg8kBJCVlbBsRIDJBrj130E9ibxpf1XVSrxdqxktp4hBsKXuD2E3@gaITgkYrQAVyStW1rzbvMvmQKUR0lUgMSZv0SSHx3AssBgwkjRrinJ@gByiFjhfirSCcPRmirO5QKWUfCZXVAt5BcQyENOAZ5Vwzk0a6ZPuUJo4EsCTnD7NG0RaYd/r6nZf3vINQWaB77sDRc02XjabdgsY9OZdyhuuPTfmrYbaSlbZ9ShbfvhkFVrvUvGw7QYO0HbJCE2T3mwNPevp18lZT6fe1WPKZDT2xxxpzJ7sAiP11gF63TOifQ8jKFFPZWsprIKB3ykrJoQsjCrgAzGlQIeCkRaanoL5koDpRfYQWg7QrUgEtpjN4OXgezwidASFbmz3phP3aI0E@RqcLfXGgESabO4ilfZwfnACo2PY8pFKQ@UikWZnRhzn0XWPz1ZCJH@dP4gPsloIgWblwxlpO9zZAI2AYpF4DpQD2hVOmw4Xs4wo9ENLgwQpTzj5AByETasHA6AzEJkXZJcXhKdELstFOrGdMxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17vNXrRsEDyr8TAAjQoXoeu0MN4xunyWlUemUoAQqLORMXJwKgG4KyIFBhVB54vqKAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfYvT2gYl2DzxdJIxSioEnts/jEVXalzxVdegut@QbeCgsfqWK/0o8DBCxvcaBZEn8GlLgTZ0SBPqX5FvS8H7C7Aq4YQomhhYl6zRkb9lWZj0uEiWSVtiLE43wR6Dy@sbERr8Tr8TSYdsC0jaYdNKXAtEMmiUwYTkYTxUiTCX0bFAPdWvHLRgB5lmxhG5gh5/DWHCf0RqWSbaX1huq/NXwnoSoA8xBawhfAiSdrNTQmk2L9DNdsgH@PlH0P287zrmuOfRR8DAwBt/s4yBISQLxHbt41qiib3oyRUc0FodFAFjPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpjJ6t6DeRDIF6TxEgeuM50DIxbI1eRgLYlG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkJ5M3iklUzrHdSJuQJtKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQT76JkgZlpWIy@clSL@TbCVTcYibjKeBLNficcALLTh6VGicEeCN6KE5A1RCx4QhLrqmQASSFqewu35ujIdzNxognHUDLhtn0Bf7VXBbD1LxKJV8y@NHGbolST/ge3k4YG5x8g75pfGcU3eB57SpLO2OCsbdU6k/cia68okMQpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkJB8OiYr9xPSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQTB1cj4dTIJbBFrU0tCpzLBjdocPim/cAOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKnIBLpI27FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGgHFe3LE@rBuvQBzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrQcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiHBk9wQL60QfyKPO6cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNIgJdbC2hr5HorjjXvyZAZRhQQOuFFPLt0B03nGepqmFbr5fiXww1YByB5CJaFUaoOIG3hJKngm/Ure59NCgYz@9PDBPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U@Epfbjoy7EGa7UN7Mm1nZAIagvhvT6wjx5lwKR8s62ZmuNBsjqaWTnM@V6dlbozXdTqORVNBN0VdhJ@6nm7pfBIq8N395Anw@i@On9fkSiSQop@Obkwb5yFXJ8vxeRBdc6T11mB5yOMNU9zMizhuBTs/kcz4HgX0mPr7PqGOAvciugddCtdQfPcSuo9wzyfwyv4sAllDRz9gmQLiPlDc9OY7nquZS3RfK4OF4VQKxxnHRW7PVY3cTyf9/pJzlpxPJCRN1sI5R858P@iSjBjNUp4Hws2hS2GigAoUJtwjujZckcLx3S1yuLL4JNyEMDSsYGnxCDgWXD6DQd9CvgqEFmTR@T5OAzjsMa6SEOnGtTfWBSbUuzafAZ1tLPHQQmyDOhAMbgqyNMKmwvy57yp1Idvx1yw9TlYdkPlpWmW7zle5UaZyuTin8Fn5zTaA2K5Xgw1364JhSvF4GIygUt4gBhWTFvavFTXcpuHRZLtAUaqCp4A4MdMyUnNW3G9dxBWP0NBnYrM5u5PRPgO5BHdMbt5VBkaV9jitwVc18In7PGxnziTg@DAUn7juDoHOsNRsGZVQP1O771g9ia@SQYNhXL7CCvI3KYQ7Of0Nu4bpBps4aRctj4r0NbL/8xrcK1Vavx4gsmM0BATd55xdnKRPL1gDhrxT2Rtb5qTFLuWJ0x76O6Xsq3tLOQ/quvrcE/w9LjW2e/TRJ41Mi0MQRjqufJV4Lc6CLcrAOAOjhHvJwYQ7dSbmhDgB2olgYnlVGTI1o0USyD7A4AlUWZiQXyLM@oVxsShL3wBJNWFgzr35KM2M5KXct/TJxLB5m@PLj@vRzdeJ/GRqlPyOv@hQYRlamQHO1EQ/yGKVPT9@sH90JEPL9RLxfVzBqUB31LtDYFDWFTrAZLTwFXanF2d3ME4SxXYBuhpIH20/PjTqKjR6kD8gdaQdA8NNgGMSF1@64EzrXRSRc2g@gnC/VXdCOAqBJYwklImAVVbm/4XNRS0/nxVo8SnCJKA7cbcCuDWT8tQ238geDDTEt0KQOBdWYbyobSaIim2qSX9D3QiXjkHCIqYRStBoMOktUDkILLJWq8r3AEBYFMDcAWJXFKkqaCd7TQ2qvgbOwNIQBD967R172chI5VZqcxUo2lzmb0Ln5Y/ARQjLoD1jZbKbCerv1zoyzwNfC@SU@wWJ01dOYFTYJjeIfM6Zggcbpojo0P6q5X1Sy7uwoJMhKaGpGCxIQBJi/hEBv82SP1F@kHkwGjkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiGYVMYr4zKQPoEwPXagNI/94wFR7oB6q7@RBPtsUxADMWt5pRZ9OAuvnF7hTqVTMRqPc4emfeLQek9oamdkNY8cYRh7dGJdj4mbUOmxFDTMAw@rrcudN@r06bEiAC17@Avq5EAT6j4vDEykrhzRi@bWV6S8vIlkKVl/eyqNtGBm0ptbQkrlEgXudzrmuqCABNwXFrxXBAMihe1Zk3OyGpw3wKkYGI@AcHHpZVH0q/uP2BLe/X20/vs/f6MH@L9eO0MYKHDmMTS0YejGmpL6ayvLj4oWeqyuWD5BPrVMnRBDpttAdnUXiqRboWE1aFqElyQY/ke4pODXOLRNfADXeEMz4znnK4LBe3UiqxbVbCCZ3XVhr@zH4knR8g8Idj1CAmeCTIMiEenilWDM@BJMRMRGMnZ7poJNU4waM6/34XQy5U9gXG@tRHOM90190w@Zyesd1VD4zvUbqtzVT6Y9RxqfDEI@tbAi7KL0tAYsATvgLwe30bi6@LyAfCd48F4XbDG0KWf0uq1VePbUG0sdksJ73EYdYXRDCq7Fn@uCmP4BvtCwHmumRY8PbIk@dGgo/m4IBfeaShGkmVfQbOmdOfIgwy/fysKdBUBxat1UKpNds7Q8Hq@Pj5IkxS@XV8eeyV2Oj1VzBArfzyrxWTQqsL/D9ZZaheHKHOmWpPUixrXEfNXGhGtBwzVNioOHL@gExo2NHAek7tTS3YXphia@yEewjLBuRtofNp6ZXQfYgTFTi7KqBUNHZMAgkhlsjVskhNuJ6RHZ/mCuQmNwnEQKTatJgNOd4JbRNW3qAwga36qJG2IjjUR21mGq65zhvZZ9GIJoyp@rR7S3K3P1AcRJsrqWDuP42uFgaXIQJx9vaahnpmfQYzViT1ZmdNK1Vrovd4Fg2i86jXdbs/ZMy/HYc3rehKCBC1jgz9UNOopLU7clmgyPmm@gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDY22tT90@0n3//aEULqRQqnoLhQrYH8dW/fdaun6iuCe3VRAdWHRxf2vEeMMQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2cNMiWLKCp/qW5MwLrmc6fPg/XMMHetQGwwd4zmx08DdYYRyCQwTl7PYP09quZtT630YUboGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR81qVMi2jfskYaibz4SSqb02NqbFS0DjsvDbwaP0NQsaHZyrjF2PTn6nHxQE8mhKGeutLhh@Uaxyn0XYjMdEts2vczsosE7UxcN9jFJ2fgeEZGq7HGNjT8VKtLkln9tHNKBuOgy7t9JZyhz5flg6VbuGUlvhzz6D7RomJS3i4QayWz2QyPgMTWXFZstwkSWXDuK9N/lxKmFwWKS/C4iqbGzGuToPQEt2CuJYEaesEewpcLiu2aRuTOT4/kJp2HMf6MjUFRBUPDDsgrUq01famGrvG7viHSNhi6sLDCY9Of92kBR9tfNkS8INC802VHl0S@qDalHDRc4QLUsvWm6dvIgtMt6WCh1txTohvvrXW85L@bIgql@Tijb2Oc6hOx7B0/poVcjfBK8vZG@EtEw1/sRYXd/mS7mIpPnaFKI3ngCyzB1LK0BgZZL2By9d7qCbDf60NNHPwXuc9M4yuMts3uusCjE2gCzY@l9aQI8zSxLFBvprgPj@UUyzcSeq7rqPAwarfSiQfjPSBwfW23EQpFxMWuJuGi3UL4@qpiwrfQdOFaAuFHOubBHSqE2PuBe@VAJ/Mu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50A/oLev28J6fYi1h87QHhpDvm88tK3rHNAeJ1zPzk1Zh1wPhriVbTxe2uIexaflWNaH4BNJIyeUjtNfmad9PPyKJ7e@FFx@0t5/3Tp5p0847UDD2l4zNKYwLnnOxBkbEtnWBbVwooc/19HQYJH6551BulHOB4wE758X/q2y5UB3JuMxvdpja@rRg6JKdGb5Nr6pz7em0KZIxx3Ib51RR/YdZX/fCi2BryYxHXPSHeKhcd6yjYHT6Q7N2zLtK6pQgikfbv0g2RUxYzLpATrLlgnodecytpda1P85vg7WVbo/e8SHtdBwA7@yaoaOjmVLY/2k6/HZUDSxCk4IR3ojP7xdoePvlTdTc7IAGtnLFE7v8mUJNKzLu797Yi1nRWckFmTY31WxtpUSk44MuWRkgOFR1yW7vM8t0sWyWf5Yl6FoKSlHkX0pXwbd/t4fmh00I/O24L7UvpY2La0c5OzhdOBdJ5h8ur4HLBo@1k9b0F7myJQ1jFm67b/WoVmzFDzkCO828FxT48Y1lfyNiyoUTrUk3THh1YYXVN107RyaZY49/mRSf@1SnL@XCWTxq@uFHDfz1cK0XzE9o8@XQNB0G4s4clzciQw8iNTFlXScQUdizhkvTrhsZwBEXbLYInAQdh3bsnKb0OrqD8dM6bOnxkDHvdaPzQlu1lzRKqjJrtpedCvsr091z/z6FEq2rrGhxga@DOlGj/ajbQW8J/rA7D5aqogwkz6C/Z2e/LXU/NHpel2cDU0PdzSFhhsmprDJ8UaMra4NcsOKkFfn7UNlFYsOxI9Brgy9am7dGc/xtNicTDdNq5sTmmX13@tEx3WbwG7MxNl0NJ56/mt1HmjPVHQWenRC7t6ZCcClN0Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTrsCF@YPiwriOG//ctJwB@7yUYcC0AROGzPmKhnMfhudnuCHHtVe0REr7A5c9caJDcnnB3kDdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBGwvDRw48oaA8xqd878tCkI5XY@Tx7bz@4mjyLeM7tLznztTtGmgM9Y1ExQI/VWMv2H2MJzoc1JdyFpXSuo4F3QsM1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtqmIs2AJb6@/@RFMtoaaLf2bVxooI9sYVq7YeBKIzNtYMTW09Hl0IEs8YDrSTqircK3xNlFZU5dItcPnFXyzrM5DCAfLDAB8Z@OHhhdXDa8Ne2nzhPHdmA0GgOhHB0Z/Mz/0kaP1REx2mM81Q746d2azHMCu2YQ4tyGPjY6UL/WwvQhYxEH/ECf6GuGIpobJPkvNN3aVkyrY7ivadIvYl4n0i5n6JExI9lifYPhfVCadLucJcb5uKU@srRi440dx@ZPorYZeKlPbqYqMBTQ48MXymXciL80L7BSPlsu6uEp3yVi9LhSinVldY2OY/HnDXuSbJPvCdBd0/CUx6jjgNwKOSYB9@XdSEOKN9KQhWgEnOyp7tEi/WpRYwFSnX2JLUBD3e06uBLmG27YnRNRTHALmQ739vONAx1A/Awolt6d@spCb8uWNeqM6LFWYIjU5pHRwVNBHdLmMdFn1yuTzwz5qgwiO7pCBQABucJOXWCJZyCNJG8ftpbkqGWsmmN6EKVeu1xOm3Uk2zS6b3WcNXMIX4u56SV/KLPylIxr5qoj3YhmkRWdTrqv7EnLW9eAobEMaTJ0QeZXJjdNbwdqVlash0xHBi4yL6/CrGVdHW9IhXVWr6eHxNU1JF/XH9CSUO8f5w@l3bWcJ4KH/@H9jxUYhNuFXKB6BEjX7Sv4kPmpa/uvD2mBzxxv0jdnh5BvPAWwjpxgsfIQBV68Z6Bpa10hoPbsqcVnHwaRfVejHoljEmliliSLyPXEkAz7VCJFcLPrJXL4oS9lF7X3Toye5OtBwJUG6XFw/isM5r9XLKBGaSNu9lQVjthZIedv/1yF3LOAMgC/5UyksUdvZew9O3h8eCyPPXXl@LQ7xNMR1/i4JcUKWikTmZJ6rbuR9U6@Ha1nehPl/nNV2nt8IGOANfjmKxoSvHBlbum1dt4z0OKq6GulIPQ1JqsZxEfHTx6nFkc0WWJv6DojIxn13nv@PI0nTT5@vtI7Gvsh9I6@M1sb/WBfVZMrmu8Lm1YH11HPFSmtg3RsgDQKjfER18tyK3PVdcZG73g@Nj6BwRMpuPeByRfWFvKpfmoOsBey8lpEUUdlZbmQS0Z2ZoOwbbjhe119nphjpJZdein8tXY7CnIOWcXNruYeblrxv8rFsIy/E@HLRVIz11trVI@wont/34ypqroOz8/1PtQry6@trOUAq9aHLef0A5aSDV94kUInaQKtSjJv3UdelEZAuhV84PS87wjGztptMDcBCJ0LKzv8mWHPdVuitayb2IsKxMZNbTcG@dz4gAWpcIfPKSorX7nGF26pZ4kuGZO3JHzsRqLs7d0/uC3CkY/Lm0N99PQFe6Z7qITk5oDRHBsfkOMFZ/Rawnkr1IC3djm15wIo7UZ4g/Hq/lxhz3W359jz2e2LcHQGFYd2Ui4cwkIbBTIsc2auGqu6fF7r2eptRrelzQ9xOPMlPjiqnMYH9P7b/0xVMxlSPYRvNcOtt9RM0MFZAk36HPXZRb2OD0LS0EW@RQaH5Epp9LExw@0ofDZ4lVC/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Ob/Eo3@OVuSO@aHzqyrJxRbwCYv8GP5eXQ@7FjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVGbqpIOUbClKOUGdfWzotLPrm9Sw@Hl3wXytb67ExcXPjodMxcyvLsNtHJZPsCSpLv@7vb6fQXdreMnD8Ix/cvjq9s6mxMqEn@tvVHkRpTlZ6ARE0hlM6EnHde3mBtAM8r2EPTK5fkd13Jvtku0EwC088r96LYI4fTMfrcwy0ET9JcZWcLwX8FGRm58xj9/Fo3IJNXyH74/641e7reFoWTgyimtFHx7tB6zp8rmiRFBe5@OzZkjMeHp0cPo@4ucZstk7olWbrZMiVPotUnx7nlpLdrr88XYGs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBnNh9/Pw6SUDxbTgZWYHPx7q9mDFdqrCeM6GThis9n81ntI1yZU0P@S62VX5ud4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe0m6jZv12e12rPDY@o7UHYIPYhLMlHKiveMmY5YZBDinK2o7qnCyYn6XsPh8PTXu20mu0Lg7tIk289lZ3g1323HLO2ONQq9A68qCtBq6fGvY64rTqsKJUzt7MhWWvsFTr6oV/vcR/rauS@@sYtSs0AzdE3ERNMP5RV3kYWD7RkreG//h5EPz2sHuWg/P3PXM6uj0wgU2lbg/o3kD@rgI0bw@GH/s4GTqufXvQoDlVKveND8zExgeHHM27zgfkodPv3x5o33NuD/Rkak1MlFlWB33qTC3UILDKb98drHSvb9ebTbkir/NEbere0E2u98d9kc7UAxnIDIlnGFF6bU6WHIM2E3VD5e6GLdtO8grcjx32NVTjvgIVbz@wjj5@uCYcP1QONCn6QQIv7auU4koY@NF3Tw6@GpFI2JD15PInuqLn@FFtd2IT1dZu0pl9CHtxwTb8c/LgIQYn733NAKjd0rSnBh7t5x/umdQ2IZlaTc2X2Q5@E6vC1AyliZ/6K3MlgkFiDbZ57p96r1TUS7ZRY2JFZL7egVAnONdrDYBRIy8UikknKtucgM9mcGae0Sda2AWjqT6pi4pPwSYrUe0hVV@rAORp8/zZwbP958e7xy@eNzKtS1/rQFAK24bUAt0md7I9EQrv4w1ECK7lnrRdWJAcfT4Gpwi9oFwMP0m1XLTaUtEWhRJ3MM7muW0rCileUKRLyJ8k8tTIFwdCcOKwgxJTBfk6NypcBwKpcoA64qBFShMqrcIyqxIe68AOb9q@/9UvuJEvfuWvgt/5w4R9xeTQEgeO0/NT9Ax2@xWk@HD34PGLo30WZHDRas7M3mRYK@e53nquDAbqqW/STtQai/tR4lBXtVr8YRwQE5fjrEKqMkhnPDR0CBZgB5Vs@LG3WGKT4AMG42GlKP/5G8plXMZDFUkIGw8yFYdkoc1TQ9nY2GDH0EjYg6ODT/aPGOZ//wE5I4oQBDvGc/p/9uMe/@pKoEcr@MKhOyLelfQQCVFdHYECi4WODcQ59d3x@u8c0ldOSJNF@HmV8PtQgkBf34F2e0YqMK@oR0ySxjL@XUZfe2WQEDWh4EsNuH6Hmihdj52anol6NDAPfVQMudzYccsfKUOV2S5@xBE/FanTJ4Ag61N7wpWv@SqYYtDS5JDmpNkmZZZ/MEiMBIxvb0Bj7xgg1jDPNoGwTirsNbREXCOrcD0rklSPX4sSgK6QSUJWOBLwmiZJT2m6yvtf@yfKoMrAPAHzd3zzLHMfbL/i2/pg/lVufqlgQ7uueXKRl2iGUFusXwKekRD/iPvItyttrttmgThUkBkQVmaOoJpOCesYnKfAnxLQ4wWcROMTqDRoblBjvk4bnp7hthKorraiKNikUNSW6USRMePbe6@orS3kCzlVgUxKpwFA@s7EAPUWcIDJZAW6iXBqjmuvQHzb3t5mIs63GbVCldessmm/zIqvwoxuQljhbIiZazCIA1EWMcCv7keD0SelJjEqUq@4GkfC1XNgWCJ/HL7QbvuIEFkCkMVxZOCHC2b4mdMJcKG@@uUOfhg08g2iTR@QpMKYRKakKPjaYJ46E2g@0EkXXxnj2mBwezsfAlGvqcc//ktaj7E9ytd71kKJQfCxI7@vyUgDOKhs5upoGq1b8VME8RxBVMRVzbfxkjUnTbul8LbJoJn@cEVjtsH8y8pgTZvl5d69rvM2cVVjLSKL3XtuOzix@BAKwxKaomUVtZBcFCmXW1kkv0R@MlAcVKx1AckBmQKS0TXM187Y293bP/j48Nnza3pdKWT8ajCg@/XtVFOS041WaIhHi7VcJfcfKs@f3H8YVMQi04UINQbC75dEvakki/UCBLk4f3a1aKtyeLV063P8KddQcTW/We2mrFGka/lQM18iXToDIj2kk5xXE9dKq7CVz9@UpQU8JQJ6jx/Dv5bVRPL8stECrt6Oxa@3hBUd4WVM3sJOAKamt7WpYGO/XjgsWPhZ7mP82KEX7YvZ1X1R3Myi2kDUAjJxThaKFX2HiEekvEEyQCIFWQmCru19h5xJX6j/1Phnw7m@wag2tUiGC5mbMB4BdRx8gRypyEJ5sa@3d6h7Q8vsCIEWO66/N1AzGqru5RroEknB/wQOTzjhf5N8VpnJtOEzkURqR7DS7CZVwAG8pAAdGrm7Z1NvyJ45Y/5JBNrY88AITEcOkN8HUz4RaLCPpyMI16fXkUGLrEC5JYgMmIyHWeW8FFAJXxPwLIW6liG9BuoD9gsuj3r5xCwpD41ZzxwAbU8k00DR7qhqi4XagrHQpB3YjotUZ4tauLErfoTKFaJo/1Iqo2eLDOgNXTbtnjFLxM/iyUoL0kf3@Nmnp/GkuKotkepqX5dz76oO6zD7RfVmSqJP/N4ZKIheRS3K5etUAtyuAua6FIPvsZXL8tAT6PuaNeTcn0/cx2AENiLRH@ljlpjaXA@lzMiaaCbsNCnok@pcx63NUikSqOBFHjKjmH0y8fE7odtzllBq@AlWcPXsHr7emmPWUGW5BWZKJMk28TuJe8BxoWbWpABCMESpENgaNiEQMyBHvJPIvIFDHPSHsPAibZ4rvOmzcbQW5SBOqNSsfpdFvnu5zDmK5XLFr9Blqlhm0Pquk0NZAbDX6FzA1wN2fRVVgDMQf2UhtiDk1ylejNKN8Yw88nVbQXZiEb3UgcorBrAWWqO7QxfvxL4NfQX4g0rlxfHDdimpiCzUkTVwzR6ulfJPK4Qinv8xLOimylLQeJVLdB9hNNRG2uZKuFAp5kPqMOIVkhqLosHX6BwIy96ibarqja3ej@jXAoTM4QDgnyVuB@BQg2wwibrCbzWx/9nPYshsJDZV9aTtnqbi@UwVHmo1z/LszmZTkjYbmdq9TR2kqMmbWRNkcmUr9@DUGPZ7BwOlKYosy3KKsnV@fh5/uPXMfJlnBalnaoU3s/lltpB9M7vMqqU3J2O10JDfzFpiqZY@abFnzz57136XFGen8zdiM6HF9g4vRDWHIn@sUmbnO4Vs7KQM4ieky9gJewvXSZ/hn8xvexGzjuZOH0TYuMhizSZgXBWLoqI04i34k7j/Ci4u@Dfqcl3eab17l2zo@mQ2Z6Zpjr1eD25nCByklnzOQF6@C5SeR1BYk94kQeE1mvWvzyfkGZvtGoPBdF@va3jMXL7Xrs7N6cPJk88/Da4XeL09ikR763@YOZVKSFJjxTxFpa3nY/iJ5z/7ycZl@vxZe/vPvjlSjA18HeLrO5dP0Pxczd/Z2Lhz/34ul9Y0jZufff7sF3d3d3MP0vlnjfxOTspsbP/pn2xsaNq2pmy0PE9txRsnJ5@JWiYnyn/2o3j72bOve149@39@411dxUcRHqesCHQCrixTwYjPEtwq8lgfesXexqCVq7E5/dqxwP18g6n1neJ/@d7hm9gkVteUT114T2JvYoVSjBvBALZsYDuN1WPbGKxwGZsrtVoNjMX/8m8hfv1jgIM@82141PMBrMI8VpdqFOUiVi@AQdU0SPf//sY3IjnkZKJGbFxw3WMNuMRcURN3WnBt0bUtoO5RKaMoQTh7MpwYDlNLd9W7aDHBAi/bwI84GJNmDD9yzw7vMXbUSKVSLbktwSW/pEkiRVW1pqreBXIg3dmq1aQtxrWrZrP5u6ghPklTWgMHRkzj7qf/EFdslWP15wZ3JMQKG/dePajXoUzZenarnqLL70jUp4ol0XHuiSzNXsVBBGm0Xj1mXCV0XcyUNDGdTt9rk32GuJJmYUvCiz9jsdAFuyy76rYUBYL4rrEvHy62j9ef/29//v0//x79vk/3f0DlrHbP7CtbEOgUukQdrnuVSrdeF@uueN5Eex3aUaZSqpSU9mUzsQUUqHXE1MxHF/F8Nv7c/1A8Y80kxYaLkq37yaO9Hls417lLPerme/DA5MD8UpBhCWtkDrF2LRwMrf42dqlxWm9JyBDVpIZayLckHqseXGXWuAfVJGrFstiqa3ntkN1rz/jFhpsec2IgGRYCPPr5rS/KVg99FrZ61ClWD6LVF2G@bLgwv0Ks0VBaBg0IgRu7t1HZKFUKFU1p19df0DSjVgpqGMYzL3YaCy@O2dgCobGwaV51C6oitLCgBbMvEw4qK5zs1tZejGopW1DFqm/S2kysQiPRspI2aIsZVQx7G87vw7UBP/rDFVrxuUEuvjMFuX5tsIq6pWWV/J3Cvobj6y1XdKAQYJxg3U6n87bbAa5D1zt6V1cn@lSf6XN90pl2Zp1Jd9oFpunqjH7WyTslZ8Zm9JelWDavbsbu0iqPiv9sUcsWctliIVtUtVI5WyhnS2WtBC7ZbDGjlfJZDRxL2UIxWwTHYrZUyhZxjMsWCtmyli1nhdi7xgY74uSsxVLB1Uzder2Q5bZvJIODtyQ5s5gQ@we46qqmsi0Y6DLwAO6OjCB8409VBRYDju289W6r8W4Leno9tU1UtlWX/FzCS27fa6Wky8sGmKtV/79dD41VurgJCte6TKW2X9aBjXlZb6QA5EsfpCwxAiq3661t8gkT81PzvbdbwAhJqe3Gds3Zo1umnibFc0684NxrAeDtpczeu5eSwXQPANQ3oWMnU6lNSdrAQbbhDzoQuFVPBaXCPCSA7Tg//zlvkBiBHFxuX9YvG9uXl9vb8N@m56X/BtfL7Wt/ei2uNWEW/i2kUc2GUm8qTZ/qtMAuK3V0kZUmGOrwhnCNrFZqNdAAl9z6b/MvpxfP0AWz3JIh10Jsi23FUOdoNrYlxF69/@J/wbv5/ovfR8aTwc@oCLFzpA/KFoqtZS69woPZT2z2hF82mPEOrOiCDk/q6Gjzh40rW4rySmYVvniQUEuFpIwjedvpt1GNicxeQdAl8oKkk4laqSC2U@pcY7FtsVAkuvkL1654PP6PXmnlYpzP@KAejlee5z2J5HKRTwhc1TKqpF7U@acm@FeBfmHV9Y9@Yd0lxC7KzKgAfhKMI0aIQTuKKYokwchX3x7hQQ1cc5FQvD2tfSa92JVwPkaf0Ipal8811A72a@VynS8XbT6jXrP1YAueKvz3N6AYrNmHsM1@rTsCTrrZz@a1Jn6XICZ13uDv8Vv8seMu/o7e4I8dv8Xf0QR/7EkHf8dv8Lfbwd/xCH/33@DvyVv8vRjgr/mVbFatipvnhJmUWlYvN2ciYaga26k3vzJx5xXLsBtmr@V/ciubK7NkrPkVY9Y1xpMKd@zHf/rdb34zXqvFpTh9yCinOi5TkzGGAfFrrEA7qlATUDwvXr0X/0qDRP18udVA/xZ4CbEa21Q31YyV6WbUjtoBg8kyLssMM0O1p5JIlDFYZp6Zs8zIUXtgMuCXAZOZ6bPMgGXsjA3BwBdMk3ZmgqY@vAbw6wMgF34m7kvuqJkug4QsFJvoG6lqG2NmLtpNocHiTHxlgEwrq3JGLpgt/LJUQ3z1qqlstbRyicnY5uR241Uz3hKbIn5tQCvnWGdubDRficACZETeNtGFxTwPBOVqTGk2FY5GwBBh@fKy3d5/@qDdVnCUaj5xDhf/w8NR1Hrjf3ToPDl0Rg78Dw8PoWcZ9dS9FNDve/dqQM/9106sXt1pVmhUCEaGmLK906xnJTQXUkDsNXRLfclrARHe9Y2mED8DQeUMZJxqAiSds@pptXpGhk@5FQxtNKNj@D/zDf6bIFRDOekMrlMCSzY0nn3aDE3coHx6Bk6fMpDvwj8IklHrf4W/@d/W/8kLlmSJRiuZOL/cTtCVxF8yeX55fuk/68lEwrcktuGHDmDHKOeXdTRSoHMwNRLJVvLykrvBM5Hc5gDrkMx2neIuwsGoEQuTpGT5I/Ff9w1J@1czXgX@msvw@Qz1o5hYZfpi/06zOctkktVO8CEVXI3WL2iTRLJKX9Hc7DTU1p/@iD6Ws5OkQPlctapuMW7Rclq1mgtsxVK1Wgosm4lE@fpVz@yoBZBzcrlksloFy04ANgNWiNtg71KsxprwbN29yxMpaRcXAcxsrpDK4L6pajVIKQ/JGp7e9Qny@cEhfWcGSE0@hh944qQkkaGvVOGXEONiRbx7N9EzcPN7b2c3efeuVs5cXIQu4zE4qUtO7XbPdNttdM9eXIhtkfbblPNgz5QuLtRMOaXGk46beIqf0ISkEpLK7mh1SrUMZF7LFcHbz0B@e7uQq9cLOXAplOJJXLvnJB7yGxfjVTF2TmVQS0VOAcUqOkf3IUFfxnGCnV/GqEJZLp9MACFNAot4GcOfizSXD0f5fBIwcynykGq5zIMmWa6QKKXK/q@2AdI/8ED8h4xcNpXbKm7dA5YYf95s1YU0uXpu1NTL2rlRwdn7y2rX/xg56mox7t7NlgFFpUy1KbTbD3aPd9vtGoxlyEfBAx2JuguowsaNV6r3qF7VUp5BBXJHKQ5DAisBlhVtK6@WECuC2UfdS4ADgYthG2xD0OiND6HMUbUBjiDeQGo9uFiPddgALzZAqZCZzKKLWYz707PbDQM5/PJ9QyvFJcExcDHCS/C7XZa3SRi1nz3e3ds/TmvbEotpD3f30trzF/djKlrzCzt5Z9F@tL/74PAFRHj2eH/3@f5HB5/sv3gG7h47W1wBlfefi3fUtMJ@xj4VXrtvdcPQjalhtM@m07M37LVptk2oPWsKhXIGLvOMNpRlrC/KVYW7a3r669e6O6aLvf/ht9//8L97/zvfff87337/O9//6Rff/zbcP4b7u/z93X9TzuPzp1/8s999/9u/A47/Ae4/gvsnP/3iN77Bb7L/Mdz/KeL2x/4dCcdvAWD9yk@/@N6PfvrFr/4A7n/p3z@4fv/aT1bf3//W@hvjfe93bw7z3X8L9@9xWEHY7/42d8P3tfC/zcP96g/e/4t/x/9/6v/Q@Dvv/8Uf48O3/NMf/Ol/ev/Nf69ppT/91@@/9b333/rm@2995/23/rH2/jf@tZqJPn73/ff/4K/@8Pf@6g//R/r/mJ6/9yH/9z/4p3/xv/7F//4Xf@jfP4H734HpJ3/x76Gr/O0f/BD/3/uDv/2jH@L/f/5Xf/sHv/63v/I/keE3ueH/@Zf/hj//@tf@49/81nf@6iff@Jtf/8nf/OYf/NX/8av/12/8x7/@73//r//JN9HxN3/yV3/0K3/5zW//5bf@@V9@84s1z2/f@PziA9y/@Adw@fB8fgicDynXl3X54ufKz98HG4tUoJ1A6/7l97/xS9DA/wVj77/9YzzWCPea/481lcL8mNv@P2DQrpcZfTJggvvX33/7u4ii/wFQBP8QX98JLUs@3PKdhQXQ@lsrIv3yT7/45z8iW8yo1Gk5CAfrklZKbYFAs1Uu@wO2v1IEUX5pGVoIwE/pO0ihlvy@g7Tt/Q@/8f5H//j9D3/z/Q9/BUdrKVdO76Yl9ZZlNgiY/4BwGLDwIeEw4GeQfjtFU25S6jOwbXyWL2Vt265@9tlnQvtCwfOz9y7YZ/BjnwUX4154vtb3CvzQHQ/cMnBvvHrVwrXZiJuicuCKxt@@F26dh5Qk7U5qR1E17mVcKJs8FquCQ7aUbUayrvT7WxX4MXhUKlvnaWmnCUwfRb0UjKBIqg91Q2Gqns5uZXUIqOR4OFax72VyqeKWroMInEK4KeJ5tgIeLJ9ls5Sf5IzxdSp0h0CzLTLO8Emu6D0T8EH/ImMllmXM5v@qwFI0ec2XUFILIxn8eH4S3CjkIZnULFwdI6aQca5si7vQwjelmyszLMFslpqBtA0GSCEFXveB76/VUhixxrMIVl6YeolRVlKpGpQbY/M46XYJQczuExSIWUsdsfZWbcYjphBePUBHSkCnI1HVxFSp9gASrM0eMISFwAnsq1e1eqk2qyO4dxw7qVnqPuUJgdVSs/o7sNcIJsQTYg/eQVZKtVSqXsIEsZC8etJtXkl5KhyVPcVSfh3AG88v7Nxj7I6olkS@6rGBCOOh8ZlahMaAEBz8m6ktvzj0D4x0bxHCNygpPxXG/XeIJ97hbDIGALiSJMsygxs3FOywe@A946BSlCy8UhxCiloEtYDQgeFEVEpIUf2myALpx2pbX/pCYFiYzc1NIVYXs@KhTKhTFOaeVOgwB@5vRDmmwsRCWURng062BHmB@FVKfzOOK4VxxgGzOyl@37u3xe5AMem9cBOYlMo6OSfGoWynUqIG8OtOSngJ8o8A7ZQAXQjyrEYrkykhnWZMrsXQjx0eHvqZIIeXNSEFzVzLqmjH9bHpdBqDGLKcltNp/y3Tmxxk3yCTr/@WNxG59DF7pmm5KohpVYZOLCpTqSBro@O7d@@gVmjDWOUApFzm7x3TciXyBAeuvsiy5sERKC1XFvgUAFMLOcYSNNULV5LhWZ8ENKSkwA8a8GwEVyKulUpxCgn4lxNbwWbCgkoNAmd6Y3XManBx6bOUTwaee4ds7/DJk/2nx@NWiwn4cdLpxGiPXadreF4C/XafPuCHTLRyIRlrNBD0cUVDEiPsVzKYUOrgwdHB8wrjxfYrIUEZq9JSsV/QsirExuNPt2P@ZioRvzDpiM/xWVmULaGVgfwlY3Uh1jVQpsE9AChrV1lVeOIN7jszlsikRTGtFlCmTOKKJ@TjF50pQ/3HXFkS9Co8eiJvbxMGhPq5RIsoaIT6Kgj1ur8NkalC/fn@MUQ4PmSqlpGF@mdsJmOC0qVQt2qWYQ8mw03czyc2M2KkTJuNTBp/WjYLTzVXSKv5YmtjwzqXMM0mVds5bsy8BOu5hMX4KlxM@KrAvgpOcEEauNuS@VtdDw6r/n5D1DSY4JsORTUPHS0p4JQ6ByeMo1cV2vfykpQQ2/j88wmr10GUlw4eCjGgF0MWbLmTzJ48lKmae1PXIN8BYz3zExM/HSr3TG9s6XPoPICN2OXlZR8gHTxkWl0jK4/Rw@dll1w6YL6c6ULMrlRq79RcUTjarVTeZTVNAAdhS8E9fRvQAGhrxJbCf1UPEslmSwrQKlUU4ZXNZgWcphaEiiEw2v7yLlOrSbwNZnMq7X4R8Gs0@qy2WM/2w87uLMJmMzws@oAHG0xclgn8itzPtxUEsgHScMMfffu86nfPzN27WZwvyeYy4cQIlZhdQt1sZnNZxDgeqGrFckV/uUYUxVZMsIwJ69XAHGvCg8/9aWpMZGhDspEtZYRYI9YQ/v9@@StS2@N6NqNuK2Mw6mDMbSs6GDtgzG8rHTCaYCxvKyYYp/WsmtlWpnWBCdtcSTFDHUg1cWLMUCc6dxPrnmH1ZTxnVRMpAU3c9pX@14OI9V6t53SnuMWl2pNN2zZc1FjAI@RyYtWxUX1mDRXpkI4HlkieC4PaGelVEIzaQEaNTK6tW0JP7ji9uexN5haeWLIctxYHTjUeeCygG8DC4PzcTjabqzRYSx474x1ByxdTDTUDYw/eaimtpTeMnWKx0pO7lqG7O/lKvpTu4WEof5luJ5@pDOTPnjx@NJmMjww6IbWTK0ME1GGI2sZ2SpV8vtVoiGKqQcm08HvtnK5JGxtADAy9J8EbF/E8SSu1IHLPdGu1eHwnq2qSWslmSpfCAnGIcyxhXcCoKSxZGvF@7pOOiu3YQKUqaT1tnhMWKv1@/3LrPLWwCPq5xG2An0tJT3fOQ2tVioSrsGlaMhee4KL3Ad3n/vpkRdTyJbHaqC7sxYJYbV0K90ZGz9TxYFQzc349VgGoOYcag4SaTLisuI4zqXSMvuMai4BZtRAE5Bm6HiAnXobJNTOY4vn15AqRQLPz61ByefEyjBVkS7i8BLxzZAPafQ3UddpA3FDLudY@0C5oPtuBcmoMFnv5UohtHX2Srdehqs9zRS2Xz@W1bKGQL2owUJVzBZDXMmqmkMlrGkDJlUvl4iW0a0V5F6NvT7K986C9V@jrGwm9wtXHNlos@e6paZ2XshLPRyJZvbyMvRNid44@0WBkXXslYLT@RJPqtWy@DKYsmrQsZJgJmiZpWSmrSmoW/7cYNPx/eHgN/ho@IVZWE45Rp9RTGG@BR7DZY9RNM3HYsYNfJxuw@0Z3TYi9oU67u/dcx/P@HmHu6/YJ93pgckXOodcjHT/R6I3MyXBNiBfjEaqjMtx/MAj7ow5kEMkhD3AfHq7lOKsCFNmLZ2tK@ST8dAIgg387AYIfHXz06DjyPt7f3XskFNj9w6cPrrzyfqA8e7z/8Di0FrlvEDUfgvjF/cePr1r9V@7wxVF/6rh4Cw8PX@QWj9AJDw8LObiWA4XOBMR/oJU4UmBFQIbLFwODKuCRk7sgV9/1jfnCwphB46f8ZLTphUcg@CH5inAcHJfWGVLajsG6XOsYCvqkEdQXAtRiWRDGzHbOWDHDeo5l6S5z@v0NcBzqePTTQE7YsrAlYtJnjmv1zsyesSE8wVOmZRWCUyaERwBkNO2SQgvgglC/NIxqNsOls441Ndh0zNY6wgud0OiagyGMwWdOEEDo6DqD@8teEN@IXpObHSY8DXK75mNdDy6AOFjKi@KeKD7SJ3rVNYovq16mUnnmjmE41r2BsT@DFsteQA/S3Xm6lM6KE1l8yOR27OWWtjXA9RjLGaP84o0bwPA3WjvNv/6tH//dn/z6oAaUppnZy@RxKml758njnDMZV7y5XrE5Q6hUTyov2TtWr8aleDZfAdIH7DEjDtjnkmWSl7RyKV8qZ7VSulQu5fJqIZ9Pq1oahM1iGaSNjFpSC6V8WU2XcmXgUnJl8M2Xiz6PrQRMtbJVAbB2F79Fv00ilzwE2YovpbK3CT3JYnponzLRgDiigPLthI7Zb5k1GGCZmmHZIgOIOuuy2MOHe5mHD0XxPlpwK8peRhR7aMmXMpnifVE0yGevhByX6PA4JdTqKU64JZO5D1Uw5QDwgxiiOETLfgFnCEXRRMve7sOHmE4fLRrGh2An3IdbrMBShGA2WoD1JwBvQmgQbJenk6OM7qMFk0Sfh9xnD/xE8aMgO@hzxINxAI@Cku7uiuIBt@zuos8eFTvPM/o1tOzSJYouWKBriOIADAMXOqUodsCIHUQUu2DqznVwG4EJv5lgT3RRnHP0IIJEcUah9e6JKLYDd0zmEz83ecRuhSwqL/U9spTxJ4pakGkMlg0tWVHMhZYclO3Ro0/04aRnDPg1d/m7CyV99Cirm7Pp/sPORx91BoOOO9/d/@gIvfb2HgG3Mp@6nUHHj9hpw@VArL1Hmn4yml@9oNQH7XZFt1Z6fa3dzun2Fa/2vG1gDiHWG8iZfw0woVF7D7z2HrXv6auWwglgG2nDCN4dvO6P4H1f73Cv4CIves86HbGKzV9RmgkB5Qlc08bueAK01k6P9K7rVNE@q7FMGlmaeaOQaVXJg41ALshUL9G/n8CnjtNKyfN5Y1bLtGqzWlHje6n6CbE50/KmmN4Y7ajlfGVD31G1XGpWQU0fTj/O4pK6wxLq3a23LPE0uaOBjCA2d3YksaG2djS1VCkUX25NRTFZwedOtlh5m8jEM4zhI9kotnaK@UiMYjGlK1qlWARODXAygQG/g3M97UTizNBPkknMLc08QBGorGxO5TSr/cQsPavxfLF5sjqrqVWuK5xlrgHr4Ycppt2J43KQAwA328lUcP9EQlTLJREyoCiJZDIkegqYFrtcP/368cnx8WfEEtb9SZFnroHUq@pbP3q0Jx8cBjb8pIT8EDlVx5X3kGot@XCWNXA6BhlFfgSDLMh7gRueqHQdS96n3YHA7gYegVYr2VfvLB8/WoLzfOic8ZRRIUWVdITaXYPhFzfMHtNrdTDpPZagXDE9eUbDe7ter7VrI9LZAEUMYn2N0ecoFmAOPJ73UE0GRT/HU4a@R7uWuax2arPYDOC0a0xSX42c3ist1a328EMb92v3MXK1De9O1agZruu4IkjbYrW/Y9emtqf3jWeGiwpgDg43gdnAo4eJPjOSm6y5j6H3UJK5lOousxc5ezodJXSp3kkuO@GEX@iAyEl8PSj0OZ2GbddE8bLar7HESwj6BuzuJkv05PvJnVwV8HSftZPglHnVf9VnGivkqiSJJBAWdCXCD5ZbZ8la/Wvw4rBPKhXIjV/RJwAVEwPAZo88IPTYvKx2axZLSGzGkoSkXHVQa2D0C3xsS6LYkqTGRUuoS9KnQh36a3Ue02vetEPfaGKZjqplCtUZuKnFXHUI1au/nFXd2njqGlULrP48IT/4q1cBqYA7APP2IvH@l76R3JbyNe5WJVAXyA605XZtVrVR6ys0jFq2Bh6pRi6TBhkfHsU0jPlaIa0W0tl0Li0V0RUG/HQ@DY4gAwHvkbASImNiOjPLyGpaNdR0IvPK7L1Kpk8SwNQQ0lgyPXH27emIgQtUFbZNssIb0JPStiyQzXoO07claqxAMqpYMMD6kI3N9BBBHRm6RTGSSYlltxLWZgLDbB5Px/uNVqWyPxt/HbwS0pudQqqYSb1NJquJjWTNM94I9apQR/JCpR5vQMv1p1CZNx01oJbBpBa1SqPRwSIWM@lsJgulM9sXg22xLrbSmY2CClV0yYhsME43orOKyPEs3MZt5M0tA6pOLWtVQaYpvmxJk8pKfiuf4dOMPKYw9skbYpIlmmJwyD0Rjxe1eDwZr@ISx4boz2gDTSN6FgfqGr@r7ojAjIkVsaxhgAVppHPMmSB3wI5dCsgwshyIvufC5fnldl34ivAcT6duay/xV3z5ZPcQf18BpzJYSy@fvDh8cfhQYAptVwUOtLpRlavtKlgkuX5PiFUYA0ra9DVwKRuMfdmNsKnt@kv@buIBCYArkCb3BmvRBjXDRLmOfYLaHXZYHMqgu6OGpmVbDa0IYx9Q0yCopqlVXACK4REMuQ6VMTuH/G2n6ngw8mtsPtdTUjAZcJexQWqzwk/4aXNtC7/0LrHY6clGvbyVij@rZFPxB/FsLnYKlbJZT6nzeGorhUuzSkrNnLCN0lYqn9@6k92KH6UqpUG6oqbwqcGzEmfSRuxeO42LdWUvKVAtsNiVCYnd2u7gaLfK6iVtrlR396qxl22xVMzyw4Z1LUUHMtlmcK6zjlrGXuJ8e1PAXfrx2HmcxeKX8BNi9@hoqMaPhrJYeDgUV7P9NZ5srsCSsXLStxXLMS8Rrsd8JX4vFsdlj4rnvYtRwwlO3n3tlQZtNmY7gQMIdTjhBmNqPo9rAzHl1dj7XCtlnxwc2g/ch4YQa25cbDi4UsMWWxXf2R9/nbExIDXOmrXYrJbz98ir9bqkbmuoDK/IKjBs9NWClLmo845RJ4@CBj7vf@kHudl2CexaRgW7puVTWr2ubmlQsPH7L34f1Rqd73@y@5jFcX7/7/7kR1rx7/7kX9Hmu/glzflr2WIMQqJRLRRj5@fj8/NLuLhfPtaKXdtz0AL8KKpeLm7JUBqlpIOhrcQ4HoFRKqrJmCfF/B2WhbyUSKiKltzKljJJ8Lnw1ZYltEwJrMGyFzmJhbyYjO0fmXlNvbe9AyXbyea06gbUpRoe82Xhb9vwyihCPnl1wRhYuvXeYGBqZFIUVnknbb9j0jZ7hytO76QN9qpWxz0TKh4ODlZktvCwJK5LxuspZSvOQMBi9cZl9bKVoiUdElVfbtnNK3hobuAhl2WnLRt@xpZHP8MgKzl4YA1sxtZrT0xsJRWl1xOvT8xtGyxfh6aypSyOMLOtYKGG/ySpmXz/S7@haYW/@5Nfu2hftD/TQEgtlwuqFvvZz7an9tQzevWfAYAblNkEgibxmqh1Bg2hgMq4JlnTjxUa5C7IxlMbmXEePhBXUUBlwMiYA9vokbgqnCLzRTXb5voUewkKtoW6LtLEzJP@smRVEAKulzPr7qCbJhhsC9UfN1pJ4Vz4KnrB2M6A4a8KX12AAocRjOZOt@1ZU3dMh4QSFE9tpdldiAIpfBV1VW6Qjg5/YJCAQipb16PyLHuENWLU2MjwPNR8CWOa8FWI4uuIt@ZsrKM6GQxp2jASyRiE8kkevQak3YK0LR6hTa4JKj0PkGY8dzySDQy98FXgTQgLJrAszNyGAFUgK18FBEAZEj5gs8W2WTbJzs1UqrpQq3mJ5xVQ8aceqLIQMBpC66HqlCByFcOBEwgS@FVibBd@DQPHGHEMgHAYfNdBDUQRjE425AJJ18wHgwJYpNctQUVjd@8uclWrmb0koxIh/BNzjBNtVA/26rwCsECMu9OriGmGCkurgWvY7ADjKcoutDqJayqtRqIyEa2XggD/D2602CKvVBV5VLEAfn3xXtEFlEFkRDuvwy7brjFVKyZZmPku5L1LmSKFAqFs2pzdkbXPAs9LyOHPYsE3v4BoHUcnL/12e1WXCQPOfYofXEKNdpwY@DpIuM46JH4HkyB2GAuKYloUum@6IDXRdohAXWYiqyYx2kK9KOWDThRoOYYb@/NJfFEsDM3graPaRz@dDVJX1XWgQr2xY5OeSNJjhacqoEUAjfJV7PFsT@0z/ECfXzcUOZojj9TrYcvHHJPeSwcVAlFc3I3QcUG6DnCTZsZAZt1Rj2lllqCGRqoA7RBckiJRhjvAfCOOO5Yxgiw9Nww6qudVFGUADNm0Q/oQn5jQroYPTRiBbE95wBGsnJknpnKMmrIlp48n@rh2mRjycNj9@MYHX/eg5TgnzDJPDD4nnVjSzeMxED@Ag04DZhc3ILaCe2q0bBpnQdQ0DwV3EV5FbiylI3E3EvPk9XdW3Ui0sUYvaLwxoVYs41S3I/il60Lw5W5v7gXavUhHFdjlkOQavl6fWhw1doQKqwRfT1mNVGTJuNYxTogxMdDvhUZh7BqnDCVoAccYIJrdQFMO9mIo7VdpAKC@Bz0L1X5O3Arqd4KcuL1EF7qeT@BtdodlNQEDcuVrvqI0gIFVX1uGDn4QFcvhTXpQMTJN8CNdgd456oEfahbxmx/GD1o3mkkl66J5sw0fHA46lFaN8W4RWPIRC/YObM9U9A3wLEAOV@RkIyGmAGxKTIocdBj/anTe2gWiJRV2HVKaIQQf1QCFWAUdSQ7qdYx8SU8Aj/u6xz@34isFPTs7k0lT7dQ1ZcPDr8t5jq1bynhgAkfsKBNjNPa/4212lXEAd2GS@Ecl5fFwvDNDvrZWvjvnb0HoezV/X1Ii3vfiODie4sfTBiPSaofq5DxqUA9N@vBiN@Fvk@LtT2ulz4P2V8H2J5XilwiEMQQzS8/T3TQAS3e6J@n@Wa/qe5xShwTgUItG4Ij6o93AMvICkznuhyGcCdLR0KtjndCKMUAS@XTxImlewiDkPLD69rE5g0i2ccZ2XVefJ8g/iaGxASfmxPawOQz75ANGVEV/zpUZm7PGvLUUfRZGh0Et3C/hoso64fxmoFyzNfrPuP8M/Gfcf7ZINEi2MWtxlgydLrE42OpR02kQEsHMgzCXXAv0wocgAz/OVA4CQ86X3C7h7tYodoBvboN6rAUNA9rEGBBuJJTGy2aj2bI942yrlVIG0NhFQgTUOIButAinZ73QjNi3Tq2x4y052ajgFkYlP9/o1B36rYG3FSxjWEHUMDi@TNRJOhj5Gzs4Q@AXGCAgHwaeyBrsThJmshqqUidPaDgNcYFjnrGGn5kWcV@@l@8G7BJHPUdsFFArAgjdwyJBNsGHBT2Hf0s0oA6fug6ECcJK9PnDEerGi7figMkrXYXTmipVUiRXkhRkE9CO7GrtalECf6iKxhWvSDEv/fqPZn/jS2e/D/1ide6pwfIBoypEuwpuwgQWwu8uhFVWr0XqFXKgbOmW4cLItc/5U3@0hmS2lEDM4OlgEbwzc9IdJiKV303y@qFTpaItVsKmMK/VoIjzGu@WvF8EKOUID6N5frR50BD8@JyAAIzMymiGH20WjTar1TjhYLM10c4imZxRJmc8Cg89W5PJlh8NpKeDYHjB6mkBd4q7REWAp/JhFNigscg8/dTA5ffXqLcTlyj8NBc0h1qB34aQxcZ21m2tTL0RyXSEaF0BgA3xGoAe/yx5RbhK8FQptIU0iqMyoFHc5jcDTiuggREJrnLd1omwkZEMDAy/mKJxAPqumGoIokrTzPjL8FtMB47BrV53zCyHVJcdM@krv38QxxZiNtJBI9yHmskhQUZJ5oXtK4WN8hwxtjsFAQe4us6ZwxIrmG1wV6Z@VKVjOR1lpOM2GvxYMXeVx/NkID/gQg27N3Ym@sTJ5SpcaDKp2a1Kn8sM5sB28BtnEf32wOv1HMOz4xOo1K4zsE3PSDNUPXpi@GKH4X9xQ4jyyb7R8QTB39DFxVgEzdsVsrrttmmbk3Y7gfskk5Vwtzhtm8TmGY8LKP@CKRIfyJMP9HCccDqvje4keTtM/FiDH@3Y7P6/3X3fets4sue19RSI7LTJhKIkJ3YSOXJHtuVE04mdYzvJZB23mpYomx1ZUovyH3WS@c45F/sCu/f7CPsq5x3O1T7FbP2qABKUZNnpnt3Zb/N1WyQBFAqFQqEAFKo@O3sDnQhXGjVFMqxF@j@lnpEGo@J@unJkR/BQpU9GDkcZOeuf909J67uIfezD5ibAN1LYQCgYDBgXTwVY0laskB08SpyWF7i66E/fXVT9tOIEblJ@JQsgQwxPDSdpDMoOZ1TXvLE6KWbqO/h@fA9sfA/m48ur8EmcZWlelcTvq/qRk0KgjCkaj25HA00nudWeQieDSvIZepUUuDOKbTZTawPTGmWt6ex@h/jDS95ieksQf38T/ed3oClev2v3BTTs1cGY5M05LD4dDksZm/NWh7I3XMie6eoS1t6@Y12UFxGBd6BCkBrLgqsHH9Y0MBFDKE42kA3gW3gelmFTfM/mYlVJnIHT8NJTn1du7qLtZjvsBuOw7eicngXXtHifFmwsr@7WcAg6Fnp9Wes5NHe5SSpN4yC6ZKrcwDKBd@m6N7OVZIkS7uGdcsawcTP9kD4lmrHFV5XdaloHLC8vYjv2MsL252A8GEuYhK7EJNRyVOYf6Ul4xridIEQHmT3LXlqtO0987jtJk@4wIyR5/WyT4cXcQIRDquk@/D4S3d5S6lyrUNX0ci4bIGh2j0fzetziCsOTcux0N5a8jenuzHMWqwmwVIRtfd8UMgUZRiKtlmNDlC9ze6zfm5IJ@Mb7dL0bZpXmDIGalGRJN4p4uc36hZvDyrhBv9hwek@/AHgajprCUKZt2NPSYX4Vp5wHA0tr0V9ISScoFhWF5BoNK1fOPFP2L9@SOls31tmaqrOVqTMZAdkqrUy5VqZK3Qvonnld0A07oxukM5KwdqafeWKb/vX6wRC7FV@Wo@VK5Knly@UKCeTlcLlSd0goL7eXK9v8EC9XDvjh83LlJ3pIx9by1@WKGRbIMKRXfniB71qE4721XNly3G@5UfA5jE29/nIl6VPK86O8MkWIFGg3aY04Yuv1dTNHw5AmNlYqPQWOiT0sn3gfxuP/S/SfhPziYEBIxB7nA86sHqpyZtKwZgyph6YNE2xixkiu6Nm8vrfDRlZJFlTzkNZ4dhkGT2r44nJWGAliSOUTDfolBCE3K7MxUtZMdkd0dO3EodzJ2fqZej7rA22H048o83FaCcd50@VNf2VBSAfeDU8UvgnPKXRMdYwRzmTdGWiBqL8sz2kU@jqLi@59u4d4rzubibAtmCzSSwzWkumkw/HhHCob9AdZJuFUGPtHdhnelJNBCe6dKMZSQY/MG5L5s24ZBIM9@N15zbHKAbWMCELiUelYRlkyL7AsRlIq6yxNVQYfoWDJHBrhYeszx9Db1o@cT8SNx3PFTdOQKStVsuTKikkq7MPT10UwktqTxWsd/r@@b/lqSl5jr8UBAKtkUovI1/536O990d@NQm2IMFHBLMV69lQ6rV7PnWUnMO@m1U53IBI9te3OVI6SGlKS0@rA0szn8dqUig@TD1HypdIE@oS2b8iWrAluodvk2kJgQUsYXmY/fl6hj59XbibUtEbSvfSN0uKjJg1HGp5gmjZtPq7S8FldjBTe3w66393Bw2wH250HeNyA4QTJZZQPL3ps5ZKObRLb8gUitVxRIsj5uDTp5vQjiXs@uk2ObenDXnN/e2/39UeadJ88eeLqOXqc4odRi73WZB4XyGyxncwHM5YtKx4CXeGwG9vx8Vl/OLr3qZefkiUirEkZCKgWw356jLtallnyfGLsUjnJa1FUw/qcDoMgI5Wg6gSYsiNN1xERJBw5DwINxKi3RG@PV2suh3RqNnvBedhs8vRlQpTrWQxdY07E3b8v3itexEMOxS3xyK5yOfaEobb31IdXtUN1@Kqudt5t/aQ@7r1TH2q7h3CB8Pbd5uvGlqL/67sHdZXLmOIhdiMWlETX7bAVIiKvWimVHiuGvNUfjEXuOFuufD8IztWrfivEMdXzODh/cSYvfi8cbUipOi1Hx9jDjDhW53k0gr0FB5ekZSyUmzZfUMQVA0V5T2hNe44173m/HXUiypvD2ncQhbG506a6EfUgyVtzrdsTJQlxJNl0iOPDwgLriooHlB9nNwQmEPsrkBg5JPBk21eacMm/76bgYX3/zYGCN42tvd3txmFjb/dA7ezt0@vbj43dl0TPxsHhfmPzHZI445u97cZOY6vGHwSBkq/g5uLXi3g0FwUf2Zkqrc84@fYH1P3JW3bXGxq8ugr4qmasli96kD5R0I1@D9vL67mLGOoLrofyUYFylmr7L9/TnK/C33DCaY6C2f4g/y7m2KZLJfWca6PBskHjbV0PV5r2CmWXzyPOxwrhjcJ1dn/h8LOnDHA24mlHocpvwUYFe9/iJYPHsgFNFd0j2ABlDFaqisOSLS97zxnkBtXW6vbhPVVqEyNC/YKiL4ypyXqOKaZtZQAUlygaPewHldeTD8T39GFFVzsaSgb1KPkgGdRj@QBVtAHbEbWqc1yM9i4gntWafPj1fLDDx8LqSfJhM@BV7FONk/Qbd2mgkrCO8BnS5eBzssvDAXKDuBVFXCTm/AjM1u3KwAglJCjJRDlKZNs2ypknYdPBUYM2e5NQ20glboCdUNAZxcqpur46hHFQ2Isk7N9pN@iJCVRqusO8p57CQVNV3wSPknB5fC1l0GcGRKjOLB5JuW2tFYZ3LUclN6dqDLSNJIesNSZotyGwOYXAHwFDgAqZlU6LZyq@PQsw/Y5mZSfuE0di3/Zvdn5i5/ZFK8wU0FZbzq/R77@7msheZp1k7BQZO@qi38MhqZV8lNnpD2mMs1jlAGOQgq2z/mAUSR862RbwiRNPc5QbExvV9kt1I1Mb6DBZY6/fsyo9IS6@odYTYsq71MocL2fnifhKI08T59MkLHZ3QCc46V@G1tmZh0OkqxDbL6QI81k5Nj/HI8ZE9M9cKjv@phCw9ml1Y3vzU@Fvv3iIWitiQYJGG6ND/E@MibpoePA5HxssDqF36ZFmog3GFycorW3wtLTEKDfAaB14FtG67kVzPUkTc@Pp77iyM/mdP379WpVSBUgmHWk8PnNS6eapI1Olx2WOlTYBsWQnIUuy3jFfPIaZyOsXuKaDXoC/oR7kCNbtE7H8tAgxrTu56JBk0SGVdXcn8F21wRYVaTx6XL@x@6P4s7NZfbjhFlODEmWR0zEi2jOQy65rmaXwfDUFbns@OJLfdwf3dC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7fCw5thybRkwbo72L/NASuT2x8CS233bgYsk@Q0tITTE@b0lhYTa9r5Nf4y1Xc89ggM5l7soCRArdouenxEbXyRO1LAtcGkCtHB4XZ9f1/lZX1CZUnuYcnQ1mIQsO@pt6m1bdRjYecnSlOyWE6UJ/MlY9Fm/s0bzDOJd4Oo0DqIp@mRCIvU43knuhapp2cWViHY@p4FoqFcFrsvRgbFRxrwN1oDErJpp1kNzM1s5qJMPlFsG4FrunmiG9s2/GxhLXM3AhUPxzYg2yYoOMXNktn990H044qpRxQs@FpCg9ukSdN8Q@uEA6p4QBl9P9uDc7rFdCmM7EXBXjS0g@FXKath/3mGYkYSJVx0YUusa@VYoyb68ZJRc9ggEdNAAEtPnSgWzZRgRDx/eW53qJtOek52CiIlE6FrX9hcQcWPv@kpjKmRzJPVRCG3x9oSY3NksDzG7qyGvX5zpvuwhV6bFA@TVZG0nVtV4R9TlcwSmZoMzWc2xiQS5LXV1Ue3wZ5shSle@LOwZQ6ZlJ@j8wGt71OQ8Tjm7X3i3MauZ9JTBphDOjGtNwNmoiCpOjPmlEzbeTKy8SNcZF@IkIE/f0QDnqzVVdcTuM2GLjOSDZ2zTLXBGsJJQ2XUTFH/2/zqIJBvre/e99cngw2ZYDr4DVb5b/rDOExv5Vl@Y6xPuG@f/RYOhz3OJveZzgHF4WtMcy/b8W07MXiVViGRz9vslnT07SQxu/XMXgNXwtuLPgKAY3dvfXJ7r1Bet5u603hdVw/Yy2YnsxeZH@ZdS/bci3rzEGAZzPsSmD74Dt/9uEL/Ew6eAUlk4tt8DtPGvRU3pghpzUcc4UmbhWrZWp7s/U7cCnrwNOLl78cq7/1ABXkXtr63487aWS@tZ8oTcvGg51ApL1/w81yUvmFDF5CyIKQ38d2asHBTw1hK4nrNaR/2UTjYCq9l94wtJ4Ni@Wlp7VmOW9fzRt750bNj70Grmlc0@Qa98/hieNX@fNo/u@yorhr8enLdGv/@m1Krj@EMW638IM6Oy2vVInuXfaLgJ/tZiTlXI/gjO25GQGpfIvUqtazSdfj6PeXyAy@aK7ghMcGl6sG54UJcsRtVz4/Wjqu9amn9/Kh3vI5LfqOH1dHD8kMHH36gWZRkjJzMH42OMafau65h71LBoShHhNVXQxRfDaEvb4Jh1H9d232Z2Y2DAoAtMG3rzRvqEvx7AdZsuHvi98IrR2@TeQocm4OClFvgW0Fl3HPn/WRsx7Qjwox6xSNtNr7mv2M3t1DyLwajPqcYL5BgLfU1@ppbMNeYSryjQFmOIuMrEvcLCE6ax8HBkHwdixV1oSzqWhl3J10LxBFKsjjMf8rncacQiOq7XEfHudgPg9YZkEC0@69cTD1/rvBGrBb7vIsHU45gyBcmSsd4xAEI/Qz4tAFVsOYe87WPHDUf72U8yBfeoxrxPRk2kM@xpogUmH@rL3y/ics/JwII4RdE5/L1FqfWvEiRlLuDvLkAF2vZhT@OGXCtUjplAY0FbKmvmgJnS3GmEarVZKLvC1cgp9CK/ukWFMr8NtWMJL8r2ZkkfE6t32LQkruUkzbw002LOVaxgilmMlukWLiVGtjpouXRm5CG1Vhthd0uIS20WEjJgUe@36vrf5jUHx@hzuMEeUkvTKUXMum@pAtSaS6fJvg0U8XOlF/8kub7pvJpNm@qrqpi5cWnnm75pJKkedfn5Y39Ub8ZpZk3kq4UrkwSnmcSClbKzzN6X1LuZcokDJ6kH0m65u8V3fMJlpm8L7L14zenOyhk41ltazLBpX4v6v6Y04HSdQrYLE/UVEqKc9xKZQZVVd/B1OKENDjs8/Ow3aimUB6WjcThMZPfeP4i72sl40dnEg25xTg1sGaMEYtKXOdDJtw1X1ikejj5ngWCYYLRlBm5G6bwWBceW2CR656pVm5BTg1watrkEK/iXuRX/DGDPYucybc4O3FBML@Wxsvt5iyBWOjey88mU1aa4LqIfNSNmjOLpHWPJyHOFhK71i5wUmcod7A72Aa/l8gJW1AYSTFF9yRFUzrNUDbse1MXIvFb7u/FB7mXAenYg254rWpYZgR8CyuXueA@CuNRDF9T7AYnvhgMujh1ZIXviq9Qa//9K6s4bkkhWjO7n2vAskfye3jSF9KpkK/2APkKBiJpQnxxeorLZLgB27@CaMWOSzTyc7XeWDY0aMw8WpFr5qGC8w0WwN3o1EZCek5GDygdD4JW6OdIR4tJ@8lJUzuRDvfK@@m4NwKXZjSlVXK5f7mIWp@3XuI890m59KhskexSHweX/EeP0wtWRCSTsAKvhKvlx7mcdTbckrPhAgB66jUm@vfEm@Fl2OuFuRrNGJwxJqU1DoeXYdvP5fbD5BAYcMHKOJnEPez@xbAlmzukdAXEjLglHHtyHEYchl/Mz3Jc3OKzMi@HQ6v0tJm6@jJqg4Dmxkmnj9NhPrCAmwChBwqdhyMiygNXZVHis2eNC@su59iIImrAz4l1NpGQodcfRS3qGd7JynUJlByDpJX12hOYUH2tboDLwf4sBHA9JqWAQcAcJc3DIacPzb8LB6UbZs7YA9MzRZJ@fR4rNNzDYUTSNyUw9woXs3CnDj581ThQB3s7hx9q@3VFz2/39943tuvbavMjn3HjoJz9/6pXe69JuiSn6XJqvkcf8rUDKpnnhFxt96Oq//Xtfv3gQO3tq8abt68bBI3A79d2Dxv1A081drdev9vm03eCoHb3DtXrxpvGIWU73PO4VlMsl5ZTezvqTX1/6xW91jYbrxuHH7nGncbhLirDqX5Nva3tHza23r2u7au37/bf7h3UFRqW224cbL2uNd7Ut32qn@pU9ff13UN18Kr2@vVEQ/c@7Nb3FRsJWK3crBOWtU1awqImbud2Y7@@dYgGpU9bRDxC8LWnDt7Wtxp4qP@1Ts2p7X/0NNCD@r@8o0yUqLZrb2ovqXE55xaqUL9svduvw30SKHHwbvPgsHH47rCuXu7tbTOtD@r77xtb9YN1lXu9d8AEe3dQ9xSCTXLVBIOoRen0vPnuoMF0a@we0pzx7i3sHVzq5A9EGMKyRkW3mcAwg0BriUh7@x8BFXTgDvDUh1d1@r4PmjK1aqACLCq2Du1sVCER8dBuptqtv3zdeFnf3aojeQ9gPjQO6i51WOMAGRowyPhIrEOVvuNWo58IL3kkZs0ZzvW4O1VjR9W23zeAuc5NHHDQ0NzCZNt6pWnuw/@vtYkS9bFnEJzbGyud6U@XITxeTu/IzN6jSTwmbe1t12lG1s6u8mnCO5p1nk64UrLTaKZJEuk147KmHZ5cnDajXqePO6ZJMdn4OI9PPUQ2chEU5lNuTmAxvb/CBRYXm833tSYtdA@aTde7S8kMGreV0Nvg83K5uo2I/YCVNzZ@KhWh@/MMoTZ@0AedbKiHAwjkFOr/IKZvwXnoqmKxHepiuLwPwGbrKJZjkzMcpZBo5MuOiGaTVsk7E/weaXbggo4B77ea2CeFZSRn6sf0p/c1fZHJwfpA0lm2u4pFLGIZjej30FQjlbBLBP6jPRJEHa7Sj8Pw86lTsqvDmt8/7ffbjuuaMpx3ROvAU8e9pfhJeDpRvDBZnpHlY2cdNiE2625WYZLzZ00ypfvFH3LLHPxpjvjHNdiIzwfsmnJVvFmtNy2dH6Q4LJI8pV1b4HoFdzJ0vje1vzY@YDVXWnm8PvH9VfJdxhbsBeEblya8Iy53zD@vjiUDDTD2xUEkibSHjGLRKmPsTZLMV5TxDJmuojYsf2iuPgt5XieSkCJ7EXTtOjEbD6NrG3uSwy/3a2823@3skOgEto@frj5ZW88lbrf@6snvR9TD7mvZ69iA5nHS0zjJGiVbpPjwSLG8h6fszwxcLCIj/MabTuOP8POQ2G1kLZkgyNDcGKGdejDRy4egQ16xA457OcOvM0emZgAn01QXrTkPrlnFD0hXYh7QxizdMffaNf4AdjL8zRBPGqQZSLMYO/QlzqXVBcu9/I4xFeXFDTvuQRY/b/hY3LglNOCtLrafxe1aftO8bfViLKaMGK/c7VySkLg3iYUydhU9Gdlv2c@I3gBm72H05a@a3@jxo3Zwx@7ugnhUGx0QGXeSktinTjejdaOPNORjxPGAUzVT03OFXX5XI8VjT28nJ45BrNHAqCAoDWx8s4DXEz8ik1WyBeyLZVd9EU6F8w7AWdccq9@Jc2c1R0NZN/5D9LvxSqEEVuLkRKh2ldSRM1k@Jn4sDDkzZPpT9GD4/0SazID/nFacBD2lluUE8E6UZKhCK1q@MlGiK3PQYJ1upNS0P31MwXyzO@YsaZg@vbmW@zVEAt07Y/PhI7s97DgzCAAmx8aGPX4Tk7SzgJZOL/KuLo5zkl7rfOAoPVeYqWIKbmHt2GO1yzNnK3hxlSt7TVaFr6moeiELtxMe9bRkmljKq/txXsC5xv9H8QFvgCQDnrn0TKxWJzmrpEeZkQPa1ZI14bQTj0mkln678dTugbJcZGZkvz75MoQi0BvAZ7qdHNCkr8Q8N@txkWdidche8OCkHMtkTD7aZd0JG2J2Q8C53@bNEMQ8GV1hgugKdHbVl0JTzn02FEElqdVh6mcQ4tb1ibQ8rV4l2PPOJDg0wf5dT/zjh7KrZXL44uBDY2hfl/fVm2BMKHfv1mxhseKDg74H20VUJtsSujziu7T6/SGpjgHaTTh60dj11Qe96RD24ouh9l9I81k01DsSRumnaqA2yeqdpxlxTM@oxdEItxXaPvMHN@k8hIWouCe5Lqwph5jX8OiG2XSMrh@WlfM8TXlONGG3pEzE52pNff0quYSg2mVoyBSM4mRxwTabXA/OHZLhd9UffsbcDxWo1w7biWdSCyTvBUonNXrs47E1kqYP@jHvaFBXYAckoURZNtISQ1Wao59odtJ2TfnUOyZ8l3JLvr@ehEmNtRRVlDKurp2Yb61AnQkqrWjXoImz0PLKKqMya8H17cbFGHsLzR5bq/ynXiJSKqJEVO8b1RFPIjeTp4940pv81fsxRg99wRm3VkGBMHRWnKtOyznGDzYFH6Jw2Lb3REmTaQcDbL/x0qffY140W4fa7V8rGMXhmFYArWJ0XWQYTecv/bNec6vfDU6jfhTQOg1e5a9F4uFxzI/osNNh/yrm0EUSj9HK1B6nz@JfRtyw4T05l1y3XHPFo3Dg2GYKo@G4diZuInjnHEaAabxV5u/BpI@0pMzj1bRQLnv/lO3xyu76jWUflWcVlhN9ANACbmPCgkLukI74YpJ1@XR9KsPJvAwWjieqoAL3Bou9DMbPiER8DJPB2CAzZZZgNwIrsxsxPmpfe232QTiEo6VwO0SYndjhz16AINYkRX6EpUBFlZ@WrKJyinINP4R4GN9M7pUn/2TsCYE/gX750SxumcUILOI6xttSLOsV7WWUcGHzwIhlNEtikmLRadSzrh9yTIvrSajZ5PFN1GDLH1KKtJu9Ka7EiHRo4YMIe06TRE5z7GJSWVbLLvvtgApSGzmlmxk2vM1@lgc/DnFl5wyCaUtDdiykbyJVi6iEIMET5rU2yuJT@fYRs7Jy116bIGB1lsmZFa7ayRvNhW@gRDK/4lirPyRhnJ@gnjb1WI5H/cHyHal3o@yY6ZltFq1brnurIbAwW5UmywdtJm11jMfxem4SnwmmyVKMLc2Ih7B85eeEzSeJeF1tYrxVm@Nb6HATzVK7qWRSSfq7LWMfk@IlLHrNRJMMKcYdTkrXk@9HTWp482YJomHK8qrJEqMJkdEcy6MFaoJMCZXuTiHmPo37BD3aRDnU2yba2f1zI1EnjeSMy1OTlHFyCXrCcTsubZJcGnRgfAE3caLhJkIqUTivvTEf5ZULJ3AyjAQBCK04LKT7ULKDm3bWBB9xdICO04S1UBmSiJ42bAuHxOl/QjD2yq83d7TFQ3NcKB@vC6TrBBKtKjjXPEjmvjm9HjWvGcoUKWiIzyBF0qIp2XR291b92bZQPoIgpTlZW/qWPDTGVQ8JG/pjJzWvoQOnVemSmRGVHQhNFg00FmiVctoNZbkK7S8aCsfDukEPI1pAyGcHPw91CbjzXisl1EaR6/YYWVxNbhltripsSJGUoeQd5NdDUVRdXrgSgFAwpvLVMkGAW1PGHocC7HrH5rwMorqPqGC1jGFJH9kramrnOSMdRNUZHq9aOUqzcjyzYRRmAiHFYnaeFBHSWWZnSaHQRDcTFyvHk9ntSXOQQmx4XyhOXaF7JUvDpOeEgBzkuuSmEuWorLyS5mBOfLzqZhIT/ubUZyUrtTSZSvRJMDwqlCdTn5YyqZlqV1ayRTMliR6uXWsmkUjh2ggnUuHP/eOrKbbL88Qm1FpkZLQMbZ@NIOS0yqR1m/9rrJ7zpWyjYxh49s1ws/xqSoiVjFP2@Q7Y1TIfGcB3@59urbFMNZjoWAHsl85cdnFkQcgaax5TPZqFla7xtJc4KDBr2n5HvT/c2cm4fT0ZG0Oj83C4WiqVwMQntvN7Y1uNraSoX8zmLnYuut3i4Oovw/cnRZb9YcghASpmBR1Sl9CgiP3@8FQiQwAHyorcBX2RFWv9i07HDsGAE0p0HnWb5NTeEBRPQFFi9PL@kDeAGKSeYH9BA9G@X1Qy@q4CUTQ1FHMMRaVhEnyZN6dnRB586MA@OzmpYmAQzMaaieYtt7rxBTMIIptwZ7H7YvdLap6cfxV2u31PfUDwY3gKWPg2WWBnxy5Qkiw4YeTbvRcx@6P1VHgZda17xchi8zrAmYnJxJkwfuHhG38/PK1fD5z80c95mlaoyQ/RzIfwT@2p/Gne1c7i7wBW@JDQvlPu82DgtJhOk5lpqtcjOH0ijB6VvZlrn0wWl/fENM1uzw2izkbXZ2cN1HSXdQHjy567l1tyQ/aEuPlP1@UOaFgSGBon@Fy5WwlcNfvnicXLUadzN6nIYQCkY79LIkoklD8nEPkMgEegHn5ET3jR/qlAw3pnwqGIKDgI1jEtd1CgiQK53P1W9bcrp1arqaXBw4eqVtukh0JB1TZrahsfNjfVNr1v4v2H6srq6rrI3G33C33cNB@/qU2CwTucD1tnw216pbQq7o3BWhtdvFSsLnnrS83q8431uHhU28S1fnr6z3/7r//57/@tWNMv/wMvm/xy9HOSyff94lLry9IP39bxfrR9vLx0crQ0OF4@XQeX/Z29hvcbo0KQmo/6w5PcoswC1le2IzXrbPY@o4sqE9PvPBh@JulSUYutuLiov8YSOYpl7GIrtL6HuEd5Qkt4E3RgcilPSCwS0DG246l3WiEM8Gi@IUoSLrADlfJytmI27uEOJsmQnKosak88rLNehrjTknpSwF1cmrEKUS8Oe9gBv2SdV5qXywX0G42amn@LP7@JTzf71@rBJ0c9KKkHnnqQz/NPee0ZfXWXihFu50o2Wg7k8x6lpEcLMDNUccSKHq8fONbOBLlzuSUO2QNIxk0FZ5ZbcF6y@uPLMhJwLT7NLSCyp5ItEj5kQpHFL0u9b9QtXyjHt3zmqg0rCk29iuHKrBOVpH@hAgWxGAKkNZ8LQSp9qhInfXwjGU9F80X3dY6jCTFgkHX/5Q6Pe3yguWipp22eM2sphDli83n5irlxXS5DM9pIkfpTBPhARZaTJb5JuLy4nBMrb6uV3Ey5hW23TzOf2DqMw5GxTZdCf1MWE4g1t024pZ6@16INueV4ReWj5HjFqio/afutclaR84vuKBro6wpcOwbUl6S2bzKS0KMMSOCIz/7K9AjjjQLjKWqiWyRY1li1@2i6jISevppOHez6cnJkEaH4s0Nj@@vE2HaLfEvEsIPwACOVmPJ1gqgba68rQyb2aTA8QXTAoMMB1UZybsb7eYjQOoFxv5Mg7TNkNjlPxzM1ZXEwDE7PA08t7vYPh8G4QdMWaT6jlu9SC@GCCUhg8OmqZzXPICwt0l3CFEmawpZDCF7QHevwaNK3@eTOCbrUDAXtdgWDIMNOTMnwa6avJuiYcvV3dIKN8pTwTk4jtYhlyQtLIw0pb1@b4WE2NXRypgZ77CQDJ58TVJORaXhBF7rARHvOB78kybvwEaDrzutbgPoqwtoz1I/Z6TTsBZnJadDNmYv@xXUl8yLGM4eiFGuknIbypJxGvANWpEf@nPUCIXOTcWeUW3CchU@xDue2aM8j7OQ7scUvBipKAtBxADO@GaLe9SIRlhMzVBoDw1cNtvwnCJ1ucEr4ja@CMVjx06Lz472ie/Tzp97xA@dT7@un313GRItkM8sW1KI@zDYSS48VmhmLXubVWKXFxtXgp142w6eekjssFgkIkaJz9HPx@GuREPq0iFD3nxaFIJkuAybF@fUVAb44heZiFoviYm7BfeCaznd@LLuK5lb@RR/KB1d@CQuzqORtelrnDDsEiu/p/nYhV07i4tOV0uOV8mNaCZ2G14VheIH5thBfnITXpErEWM7S1PPp9ww3ZAjx7ToO1unjNbVTwprI3ZNYX1LSIlQPc64nl7AVlfGFJyg/UZndpeKKi5vkCXD4iAW/p4jlTF72BSWmgxb3OZg/4/456gliyLXJ2yHCkbAyEBsR3kItALIJvnITh7pmuCzzPSdfbcF3KwOh7i0uWrNFr98raGXN9ZfXoUTj1kz3aelpaXKMTg3RzAhd0srU8j1V3vjxyX/8973fFkeLGyvFD0P6HS3@trj2dFEe6YHeHpm3y8WNxefItvZtcVykNTA9PvmP/0nlN/5CcJAyfk5/NlYNrLXx4kahykW@Lm6s0UN5ZYXq/V//@q/UhiVZsSEW61LTU4zYuqHIVtBj3qV01UArZVm6nIoVvpgFGGJhSGtzeoFh1PXK0xJv0y1qq4rLUHu@MvYoeopnw6wRmwrJToaxpyDNSApUUUFBQBoTio6ybDeM2QaYN0VT/XLfX4tpBfCLNudIqkxMN@7HMBlakmURdaAjNdJ6Xh42Sj/mE/OOSt7YlKwbFRJLOy1rnz5aJ3Z42w9HUStrJWGG63kruApPfPChH7YvaE3Vi7v9X4fFS2LJ8/LK02IHm/tFtuMuDhhSYTD2fydFUAcDooUhG516akg90D@HCy@PowWRQr@TnEmZeJKkZQ/CluxhZWMSUxa54@fJ8TCa46eqtMN/SYFH5EwdCNKKlfapRyX39isq/zDJKPl4zesCm7dsHKtdYBTEGnbAssnPcRuwO2ja49eGp3wJiUvB67pk8YN2uxnoNCe3kDeh0rzcwlnYHVTzHXHvDt@pODHR9Bc180YohQg7CIUCCzrAOg9HAS3Rq3n@gvV4WgPcpOiz1sRVXErWjs6rV/XtKkddmVP1lVR9RT0KLSGtJ@EZyxubsrOJbKliq3IYNnGkNrNiqi02QZuHPv8Ag1i6pdHBtQTdHL4BSVRLm6Otyuxu83gtTDxyFcqdPdlalMjVucX08qNncsgNauhOqNeXykhAwAtuBRbK9H4gNyCqJsxo1MuJP7@JZOPfQ4PhNuzBlajttk6cj8q01LtE7JtoxHcpFZFA@5W1bbBzMnskoBMXW0kI2jw2XvIuWKpT4cUWZzTdUeEw0MYlVD4v@1RHLZWEl@3o6LUSKII@5EvllUePV9eePH2GKGcLurWzwaCQj1XA4CwgGKxRO7TIxvdqNb@cl08IQT1dJaDPAosDOJh1Xbmucft85d6rlksaWCnPsK44jIYU19uVDDKFOAx9zAi0RnGGecf5sXKEhh1/artf6X/ib@MfkBnOuKMNhPRWP7xNPVPlzsXhQJUFMzvFcR7Bg4qrU@y8Yb@zD28TIWxdhe2potfwADE6G/YvTs9s7vC1a6tDGjBEcPZLjRXUy3CUOhizsIIuqjccGtbti6qBdzTdAhjlYkqAzifAaZhpv5WBtjTF6FimSQieNXFjFUeIlumozc7Mnb2@qu9uTyK2aIehY7i@bdlKyh17MoMDGcTqtZp7SNTV3i74KqmWSV7GqzILuBLylfk6fIC70i0EoraoYmQ16w0jZx5ZysyLqWvTtCj1I/CaAbNcup2U5l6raQUIYgSh3k1KhJiXnOfYJEtxsjsZ4xS8nK9YNqJvojhmB3O6sryrLUo5E0cVWMjdABD7NqW8NKRUQY/yY50DL0tvI5ij3IrG1oA2Q05WquHMnBxmgq1uY3GAjajjhhZof2N3y1Pbdfqz82Hbg6K8WfsJ7U5CPN@Mb1njW66oxo7pAttbLNvcwmbqN1xRImYpaYexKYIQvh2JihimXgPqjR1NexnUR5mxfZxyBdg10Eq42R3VgwSOXngPZEEv3hNXHHxdh79VZPNqWtIkLlX0sJAtrvkD26LJQlprAklIeQcQK5MgEkctKbcvpAwvFuiseQd67WIYu7Ezm6czLCsLKlLbd4pE9izP3kiZeWyxotlipYJ@nMcXzLdzeeMk7PT1XbSEOW7hjXt/jDcKd2eOwv8XzFH/53DHI80djyqQPcIdidtwvtHJYdj7MzjmZMxzcLMdnUbYH@pYr2hEybMAsMADhrhDSonlEtp2gzhRzuyEh5PzEYyEVlZxMeAPNf6xbvzjCmQuP26H/682vvAPbvyqbvxqBXPNjJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JUJXSyH2Z2L9Rdyeb@0Zau6ZauVTCbzujm/@stLfwfaukT3dInFXhMkAMHcV8/n5tFE6kdbDUaqbmFn9NOuxzEsZ/NlS7WXu1qnhYPne5FfFaFtq7@MP5PNf5PIY34CWHocBaR2IYma3lZnspledEseZdD4ZKVtETaazyjW@3VE1a6HtETlAhp3tga6oUKKeSeJKanTX6qP6bSN5l87oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZTcd4qL56iCZK2vJvLLNPpDV1uH@64f/RchwHnzWt9AIeXTtVdjtmpnEXoIdJl6ndGOs5gD2gV5zZFhFk5ORHenb3gm7LNws1dixxcS8OHuRIEdtOP@jtdQ59A0rKje2jIg2vi5vVlUwzTXLC/lCbZdMs5usW/yHuPSZ5tJnFbWvFwY3kSrQG36aF9N12srq6rw5QEr5@MEALHmUf86o@t8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/9dcnk)

This answer also adds JFunge (389) and zigfunge98/nimfunge98 (392/393).

Befunge-98 section is completely rewritten in this answer. Now all the interpreters perform the same series of tests.
Each test returns a number. These numbers are used to calculate a perfect hash, which then used as an index in the array of strings to print.

Currently 6 tests are used:

```
"1y":      1y.@           flags: are t i o = implemented?

"2y":      2y.@           cell size, -1 means infinite

"01-2/":   01-2/.@        -1/2

"0k !":    10k !.@        CCBI executes ! if there is a space after 0k

"01-k!":   001-#vk!>.@    k with negative argument acts like 0k in 
                >2+^      CCBI, as noop in Funge++, reflects in cfunge

"3DSP":    "PSD3"4#v(\$>.@     is 3DSP fingerprint supported?
                   >0  ^
```

Table of results:

```
                          1y      2y    01-2/  0k !   01-k!  3DSP
                                                               
11  FBBI                  14      8      0      1      0      0
284 PyFunge               15     -1     -1      1      1      1
285 cfunge                15      8      0      1      2      1
289 efunge                6      -1      0      1      2      0
329 cfunge-109            47      8      0      1      2      1
364 CCBI                  15      4      0      0      0      1
366 Rc/Funge-98-V2        15      4      0      0      2      1
367 JSFunge-98            0       4     -1      0      1      0
368 Clostridium           0      -1      0      1      1      0
369 Funge++               31      8      0      0      1      0
370 rfunge                15      8      0      1      2      0
371 Fungi                 31      8     -1      1      0      0
372 stinkhorn             15      4      0      0      0      0
373 Language::Befunge     15      4      0      1      0      0
374 !Befunge              0       4      0      0      1      0
375 mycon                 15      4      0      1      1      0
376 bff                   16      4      0      0      1      0
377 Eso                   1       4      0      1      1      0
388 zfunge                15      8      0      1      0      0
389 JFunge                0       4      0      0      0      1
392 zigfunge98            0       8     -1      1      0      0
393 nimfunge98            0       8      0      1      0      0
                                                               
378 Multilang*            0       inf   -1      0      0      0

weights                   43      2      1      8      9      1
```

`2y` returns float infinity in Multilang, and computed x coordinate also becomes float. But `g` works incorrectly
in such case, so Multilang is handled separately.

[This program](https://tio.run/##jZLBctowEIbP1lNsuVgawKY5paH0kENmcuqhR2AYYctBxEhUktMwGZ6d7goMDJBOmTGyV/t/2v1XS/kmfeH0OvSNLdVuV3kYgVO/G@0UTyufiiEL7wGDlc@ckuWTrtWvjSl4GuS8Vhlupj1Im1D17ym51kYRA@OZX9c68HRiUsEq7Txh4n5WaVM@m1K9cx8cjH4ALplX0hULnj89Pj7nAr6MoP9VsFr@r87oVdWYF/Xt/qQO8/oo9rUuFI@F9ICw3WMC/mcrueaUSFhas@D0iotDF/nEd3NxYNwJwQpbzxal8y1@HMH9u@ktHWMG8/cHjQfTrFbmJSyYrniLOYSobkoVUFjjLRqsnLOOd@ayBEIscAbK@Y4gMZVNlnBn/1DZuFxyboIwDwGsbNZxVoSY4Qf2JoPyhMVJIj8mnBEHV7SjipgeKtuY8mFiOj3Ya8nUs@KWVhueAv1SgSayYqGK1xkW2qxMezDLc4hxD7oCaTZw2IdCGpjjUWpl31TJcNpF0NbANYV9sKQxRhXKe@k2tEedjqcsqawDXqsAGgODIS7fo1X41u0KlqAyoe1wdi/OWtjfgEFPiwy9wNb5KarxRgkxBCR86i02mCSX3o6it5cFZ@vGL7gmxZaR5irhX6M5S24NfIAOdK@PoQ419ddexrGeinZWOKch27KT2ZcdSefIbgAyzTYh2twDO1/i28cW5wlwy3PUHeo/OA9AlD3HYN7P@VIVIXtVG8@RJtrsmISBMRKw0mlExiBa9ImIHDaCytubupcKkm3xcSo0ztA29rrb/QU)
can be used to check validity of the table – that it has enough columns to separate all the interpreters
(all rows unique) and there are no redundant columns (rows are not unique if any column is removed).

[This program](https://tio.run/##nVbbctpIEH2WvqJDigSMWOvCzQb8YG9ctal9SG0eMbUlpJEYAyNKl/XilL/d2z0aEYSlGJYqMeqh@8w5PT3TeN3Q815fP3LhrTOfwSRJfR79trzRf05t2CaKdzSnf/RZwAUDsXZFmIBt61ykkC7Ws3xmPhvOYQo/dO3yEvKPtVMvdv5iWl2bfjNX8EHZK3pxfv/@TdcsC4w8rJePMFKjqUbryC5GXPD@9vYPXbNHKtTq52PXKo9QNyLEt919JkJGKP0ySi0R@y2KFxQgV/nkAI4o1IEcqGEKxLEVSG/4f5l0LfMKgQZHiYFeTS7Nt0B3d5RbZzA4EaKCy1/epUquM1BSTCjD1ObnIC9fv@9RRmWU2ugKlLt1lKQx93m2ISSVYseqSfEv@Eg2nQ6iDM0zS@YAJS52e2hVU@laJxwAxOCEYZ@50QcYScrFahnFgnCcd3B@weVPvA8yN2TX17f7Sh72qrf9lDR/OIDpn0irAmaz8yIprSjkwflUFkFACKqGLTifxZckQoTR6MR6qUjvc5GM4op5N6cVh/prcZKu7COQM4rumYeSy9WIgJxqoFMkCb4pgF7GP3uNz/@BVt5eOk5b172lG19AyFI6vyJsUQcSomhAbR2bT5K6KfeAPCH3mhHKBTjQAUt2KGSIi2jY2xKWtnInAz7DZwMS/syiQM21oQtWGz11LYhikKs9IoA5xmGiGiG@dzptXcOlNbmoyDaz3hyjtERsESYNWjhl0N40ml3HbxiyaT7OZ@a8PSbx@fQ1xDxcpt2t6wO2wieeLsGFZOt6uEtE1tvuWp@UJAcFofDH@dwAie4Qzxdd12KWZrFQ0sc6ThHtjctFS@ZHKslEwkPBfFhHIsy/eC6Mo7CWla3XMJlg67qAAXLke4XI9okRzQSNPQqt4GJ8i8PNjYwy2/AJzH@d@/Gx36LkZ9X6eSU/u9bPL/k5tX6s5Ner9QtKfv1DPx5Ay8XJBT4ePj4@DB8MmZJivF3wAs0YFjA6l0qTwt@vIZliiryAOHpCr7xQKFiTu41TRAB/nGEpdyQTMmwyPGU4ZPjK6JHBlNEnI1DGIMeVK6KwHH9COsIojeDvkhq1fHNKR3Ift1e0yhWtMP4Rh1xMrqYAX80pSxLmzQry30q0XvOE0wWtYSFrspip3oIoEz5sWRwwL4WlmyxxXh2shirG6axp@1DxIOVm0wcxxa@HRjN5aDwIPICuAQsDPAN8A5gBgUGyDLUbxsEFI0S7TQnYc72Wx@zl9fU/)
searches for perfect hashes. Hash = `(a*t1 + b*t2 + c*t3 + d*t4 + e*t5 + f*t6) % 25`.
I use this solution: `weights=[43  2  1  8  9  1] %25 n=22 "   11    372364376371289369389284373370285329368367374377388375   366392393"`.

Clostridium doesn't set [storage offset](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#funge-space-storage)
when executing [`{` instruction](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#stack-stack-manipulation),
so I don't use it.
Array of numbers is accessed relative to `(0,0)`, it is on line 9.
This code can easily break Whirl and Affine Mess, so I skipped numbers 390/391 to minimize problems.
Second `11` is for Affine Mess. Note that `1` is a valid instruction in Affine Mess, it should not appear outside `11..11` comment.

Befunge-98 code is on lines 604/605:
\$\mathtt{\color{transparent}{\text{#######}}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 2px]{\text{>2y}}\bbox[yellow,padding:2px 0 6px]{\text{2* }}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 6px]{\text{001- #vk!>}}\bbox[yellow,padding:2px 0 6px]{\text{9*+}}\bbox[lime,padding:0px 0 5px]{\text{'P:3+'D'34#v (\\\$>}}\bbox[yellow,padding:4px 0 6px]{\text{+}}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 2px]{\text{1y}}\bbox[yellow,padding:2px 0 6px]{\text{'+*+}}\bbox[lime,padding:0px 0 5px]{\text{01-2/}}\bbox[yellow,padding:4px 0 6px]{\text{+}}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 6px]{\text{10k !}}\bbox[yellow,padding:0px 0 5px]{\text{8*+55*%}}\bbox[LightSkyBlue,padding:2px 0 2px]{\text{3*'R+:8g,:1+8g,:2+8g:' -!#@_,@}}}\$
\$\mathtt{\bbox[lightgray,padding:2px 0 0px]{\text{>82y/}\color{transparent}{\text{#}}\text{#}\unicode{x2303}\text{_"873",,,@}}\style{color:transparent;margin-right:1px}{\text{#}}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 1px]{\text{>2+}\unicode{x2303}}\style{color:transparent;margin-right:1px}{\text{##############}}\bbox[lime,padding:2px 0 1px]{\text{>0}\color{transparent}{\text{###}}\unicode{x2303}}}\$

It calculates the hash (green and yellow code) and uses it as an index in the array of numbers (blue code).
Multilang is handled separately using `8/inf==0` (gray code). `"PSD3"`  `'P:3+'D'3` for RunR. `:` in `1+8g,:` is for DOBELA.

---

*Here I tried to use MathJax to highlight text (see [\bbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/22395#22395)).
The result is some abomination of markup, and it doesn't look as intended in Firefox. I also tried to insert SVG through
`\bbox[background:url(aaa)]{bbb}` or `\style{background:url(aaa)}{bbb}` (with aaa = [flag.svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg)),
but it keeps getting cropped even if equation bbb is big. I believe this is a bug in MathJax – the background style
gets applied to different elements depending on the value of background (color or url).*

Answer (score 2):

## 390. [Super Stack!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Super_Stack!) ([Orange v2](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Orange/Super_Stack!/v2)), 16487 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S      1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse       22222222222222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 11 11 372364376371289369389284373370285329368367374377388375   366392393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^;s0::PrpullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t."6F ._#^*2*giogrlopstdisp[]!!?48[]?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4otp:sya:nlet d=/;k:^ ~ >;'-'35:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$:     >2y2* 001- #vk!>9*+'P:3+'D'34#v (\$>+1y'+*+01-2/+10k !8*+55*%3*'R+:8g,:1+8g,:2+8g:' -!#@_,@   9s)
endif #               A=AgRA; >82y/;AC;#^_"873",,,@_>2+^     $/       >0   ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7pdlWpWqW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixZ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7P2f3dNPLa1lBwFC77mA6MuyJVxFiTGXM0u3BVB8YrG9aE8NNM88wWMewnDPw1xjbntpTz@jVwZZlzDbO2IHdNXsAgU2cE8M23xou@OUYe2BYF6OLCes6o5Fu9zw2dk17Qr55xp7pYOlPuydM73gTV@9OTMcGrwJjL2xLH3V6OqPgY9fgkYoMQHVPKM6yT4mxJ47rGZCC0zU8z0HHMjjqruk83n360ZXwaoZ9pEOmxpYxu5K8qrJPTcPtXY2hsU@OHz686pplX5Mcmz28niU1x3anE@dgchV@nu0ODFtnmlyWtaueBUDmxLBKmVLmqlcR6tOYmN2ldMDjoelC7ep@LbKubkNtYV1uMWM0nsyZxOtft6ywbj2me2zqTXWLwtnTUcdwg4DeRHcnpj1gZ@ZkyCZD0wvjUWhvrHcNqWdY5sicGD1mmRDJ6ftQALTdYyfG/Mxxocp9mI5tzSGi0TX7JkYJ8gEA8UpMhgaHM9LnUMn2BBoH05kH2bCMAFpSiEH4B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjkrWd6escCoJ056xl9fWpN0qwDfoBkcj8bGrbfmAGcDCCOHZ6r11PKmrFo83qvxzLQjiEfJwYzAWuUrQrLZsGdOS5gDUIFOfKBUbvmZTRmUGdQRX2nwvKZDPjvhy6YW93yHD8zy1lDTxv6KtUZwn3mOgNXHwE2egbh9JODZ8zrOi7Y4MawvD/dBKarT9j2NovvP30QZ/WwWmS3I4RVVGPnUAWxwJOd6tYUWki0JhyoHzeMLWCVxTfiFRYHtGgZlsuxHHTbEtPygCQ1UwYD9H8tq8JdYFqJ5VToQXmW1YrxNKbVd/WBaRkc0gAhFbHxQxANnpkcy6olHnLgWH0erEsJFlm2xApFVsyzIjzLrKxBigg@x9RyHu4C3ACtDNlR4c7mOKBF24e2iu1tj/X1kWnNfegEvsvyKisCRMizCpC1EkCAdzaLdxZuytbyFYU9GQLGh/opgJcs8wQpkhESJaxGBV7K1pZCVBHJLk/eG2LygD5AXL7EipB8ATCRgywAdrUSJJ/P8IJ4Q8Oy/GhDD6NRbosZuCHnRcBDCWogA7jMIDKLcIMdaJ4GxE0DSqYBcdKAoGgamLOYBIQrgF8BqrPg42uoeyeQEE9H6xHygaoDGBWxjYRMRSQBBKgtloU6K7AcNIYsNoZ8lkH@IS/FAgNaVlJZKcdKRQb4LGcY1I0K@cKWogINVSE/KgKD@lehAaiQJxWwrQJQNZtnQgTZahb9IW4W4gJq1BzEyYEZKk4t4A3xoGWokKQKaWpaedEQIW9aHsqbz1IL1QpQu0XwA7xpkFcNmpMGudVK4I9xS4DDEjZgaLYcETriAWoFmzy0Q0BGHvJDcCEsmLViluNPt8ZDvYMUm8fs9DFqAbtCAdEIUTNYPHjnEJuQlQyAwV4A2degBWSpx8A7FyZvqQCkgeCNnklE2jKBfqkhhoppapCv9fFkgTa1QDkazyfD0E3jbg4QTxMIoDHQu/PQE3pfOvRcuBay6KoRvV0AyuTQ1QPq6kw9awEkNOQ0Sso4Na2FW4nceobe65ve8N0irzlKpGPoE9s8WaSSz6cjSNUjHgX0WHIqZqNhJ6YEQ9ZgiKZFWbQihhk7YQUtZVlVKXsdoz@1B4ZULkXyRz6TqTuBwWWRZpk7u@ZgAOPyAo6apmLSYLlwzlMOrWx2IoSOiF1M0zVhCL/LukNgKkLPModfLi9gZDWEMdc7OLJLwInBSFDGsatvzljnbpdGjkUGs4Sn7tAcB4ErawNHKpcSmZUKkbZBmHtbyoSkGa@W/Nox7UScxZPCpQDjDecuo6M1DGqf4kiFYy82XRhbHeIcFuQzYQejYxKQtjzQw8hrARmFSunqOArjmGTQmBrAMScyg0SAFTScU2RdaWBcSsajwbPjIqcKnE7PcF2GYYG99dI0zHrTjme8mSIvtchXH8ZtA4b3vm5aYQZoHNEnxATAO@5BevPlbPddZ0SDzQiHUctxxmtYFhi0zxDQI@fMWGR9Mabr47EFnBO4G5xxg8yc6cRzE4MeTZVnCCJhPKhwAEhJAcdhukaXcO8XHWJngTdZzmKFafW7WYRyP8JSZaGzALvhYRx7alkV4HWMLsvWlZ5xqqALZ7uW2S3MQ8CIATvlg@jowC9jzikXIaS7mkws3nFQs54zWi4aH18PwqIPTWSOrDN9DrXXh6HVmOkj4OoZss7Qc9kIWgyvQawJkFuwWAes59jxSQjlzAVGFgodloSYZcTJxBwZIAE5EAVrPEeZxtGdctaZQ1MmbOVkEnl4Tq4gShauIoo75CIOvLMAy9ebdhFrmLZpUwsCNslDPt8FUsndhInLmk0dbhd4urEv5clowIDPMWsRIcHjvd3nvrsEEflUw/ZAtPBkZqIMBi1/4PShsZ2ZUHYgWBB1AbtLSEAUhE4zuSsLhHJsQKMTi5msOx4zcIdBCZrnw0wJ2FDntcnegqc1BDGiO3XdOZuNoSbMEYSadJ1@H1rvW2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1Qyth6h5xCB6Y6Xi7mwbRoQxkbBZO/ZL7KBAWgHprWPEio2@UUBxmMqAqFCtzlDa@uAKSxCdzwntAixRYy@48jo3nMMjxqL456EXR8T84wBdQ3oZ/0FMRohgw6t1CbBogeUx@9eCB8TFFYWBpPyW8FHhg1dpwutEjo9VB/W6S7rg6AdYWFR1tC7XWM88duJQ@TMtCM8/@FD5PnJVfKByd5Q2LzHtq@0GggatpwIL4syEGZ97IsiOtJaX5qXiPEIxU5OWaz5teQhxOmV1MVXGGYpB6/ENXkYU5dAAYiIxHSCpASpo9kdIi2cILUhfht6mzu9XnxwiybvjpjUD9PG3KhAdgRZCZ0wH@thSHBb1wHJYwth1ZccMOiSwy2gdW@0ArITZtLqRV1lRZeBKN4GdOTYzgqogMwQLgZZ9qG6oMb4HKmGboWNkbqLt1RHSLAXE0w4kMEYOh47LvQMTnTmNJtAVRZpXb4QngjHiqTM7i8PrTBkxHHAn@AoCBHGlg5tAbsY9lSQrHSgFEDEuJAMNM/hKUYyTL2eYPn5OyPSzxsTjKW2baBwprtzDgSKB8MzJDRnpusCGTzFQYKPQcFgIlM7hTFB7/WQsiI6qN9fTVzGFr037Zizq5J4Fx3l155wqrusj0K4C0wHdKJEvO/Fk1Vyp5gRL1FxxhOFovKnCAEpkAxVnuiDXA@DxEMgNM/ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpNgwIicR2Mfg6hwNXcoPmCjGZ1AvyZblQ1g@JYkeEroRjlBD0VGD90FPgM6IUiZ5XKvo7MLoB4uk2Z7XBQJRBJVzoVpGXYvTMtHBOYlWl6ZJ@G5XTJIkVENS4DBqeQ0SCwh8AMxQRFFcFAUf2xFB@L2uB/xNdxxatNcHEtwViTJzkPmFwaABGXGBObD7JqTts@u3L0bMC4btRo0NuCmgGz2klGJNpi0lIFSQ2CZuBE/EXniPJ9g30gkobwY@JLnBtgmaKm1OjufDF3ocWS/FCAQoFWwsSUHiPXr@al5Mu1drWgbHTGQiL0OmCazOxGrAgz@vDfUbsJqfAmrIPXGEavYeDE@gb7WeMkVK1T0g7mGh@xvzc9KpIYTmAO/ra5EEY/quy0a9N68a/ksATdBZ@fUqAPZP/Ens0JClPZ5gqDTXuupHAh2Bw6HPds9flTz@yL3VDqmXVlysJyubpHzJgYXg7iPD@4f7R79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4Qftm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz8OhrV1ECnBCig1IAM95XWBoeBpguoaN7wyuDMBukUpBkGCUIy6QDFsAMDZh19NeD/Dybvn2LlXc1U2PfHXNmTXUOIHBUDuwgnoyeVxiwwKvT5yMixQUu1LRxsWFhioYM8vMRcs1XM0OsdKTJfHT4cP@oRmD9eTWJgijeBHgp3e3J0OatKYjgq8IA@QNTl6XkRcaRn6a8rkRwt7uE4EXdsjXwAQDKOrLDJGsUFM0bQt73rpaNXKVu2ALIThCu8pVRfqj7ZTMayQcOcV0UeVeNouSxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs1eFCgtDMA4EPCNLnideBK6yAsu0mer/ew/f3wt4x4xkSAKSEHOPIvJlJZnCSi9SCaLe8oeSGiOZcifEsUTmZhUlHiwNiB3PRI@I@H3Z@YkkUnyt5qEsJD67u6B9iAI7E9Z00wGCQ0oi@PI5PZxja/rQRuxHcsZOGwL4nDuMEgQ2Ka1xdwdOPa1GtLREYsaw2VCoL84caOPYawx35LgSLGi4ipfcNRt7wyotFrIIpIIQwRKofDya/1UB3Qtyv384PN9GETUfCYTmjN0AQoicQhdaOpGXMmBSZCQ7OdnZQHDJcNrvT3wkCJrdlhon9CFEXcX3isdiWLKysrwK7P0sXMN46@d@ZWmBS68aYEhgrKDp88eHzzdf7L7WXOi5fNL9lymXADEQXod4IXkIccb9tYt3jWxWAguBn3Dxe4FVGAKAkqwYjT1XCDcMgaReQbWtBq@2Jr42BnacS95tTBn6Cu9tru8CT3BzseD@hFB0O5ZKIy4fMUax3NsP8PJZOxVFAV6@XDakUFoVV53HUsfKBQPBgbLUlQUXQ4OcV7DWxUDMuPNDR6DT24B6zCnGUTdGjkgvNC6N5IGluDgadbKMgdDkIVxcdxwk3LYgqk0Sg8kBJCVlbBsRIDJBrj130E9ibxpf1XVSrxdqxktp4hBsKXuD2E3@gaITgkYrQAVyStW1rzbvMvmQKUR0lUgMSZv0SSHx3AssBgwkjRrinJ@gByiFjhfirSCcPRmirO5QKWUfCZXVAt5BcQyENOAZ5Vwzk0a6ZPuUJo4EsCTnD7NG0RaYd/r6nZf3vINQWaB77sDRc02XjabdgsY9OZdyhuuPTfmrYbaSlbZ9ShbfvhkFVrvUvGw7QYO0HbJCE2T3mwNPevp18lZT6fe1WPKZDT2xxxpzJ7sAiP11gF63TOifQ8jKFFPZWsprIKB3ykrJoQsjCrgAzGlQIeCkRaanoL5koDpRfYQWg7QrUgEtpjN4OXgezwidASFbmz3phP3aI0E@RqcLfXGgESabO4ilfZwfnACo2PY8pFKQ@UikWZnRhzn0XWPz1ZCJH@dP4gPsloIgWblwxlpO9zZAI2AYpF4DpQD2hVOmw4Xs4wo9ENLgwQpTzj5AByETasHA6AzEJkXZJcXhKdELstFOrGdMxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17vNXrRsEDyr8TAAjQoXoeu0MN4xunyWlUemUoAQqLORMXJwKgG4KyIFBhVB54vqKAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfYvT2gYl2DzxdJIxSioEnts/jEVXalzxVdegut@QbeCgsfqWK/0o8DBCxvcaBZEn8GlLgTZ0SBPqX5FvS8H7C7Aq4YQomhhYl6zRkb9lWZj0uEiWSVtiLE43wR6Dy@sbERr8Tr8TSYdsC0jaYdNKXAtEMmiUwYTkYTxUiTCX0bFAPdWvHLRgB5lmxhG5gh5/DWHCf0RqWSbaX1huq/NXwnoSoA8xBawhfAiSdrNTQmk2L9DNdsgH@PlH0P287zrmuOfRR8DAwBt/s4yBISQLxHbt41qiib3oyRUc0FodFAFjPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpjJ6t6DeRDIF6TxEgeuM50DIxbI1eRgLYlG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkJ5M3iklUzrHdSJuQJtKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQT76JkgZlpWIy@clSL@TbCVTcYibjKeBLNficcALLTh6VGicEeCN6KE5A1RCx4QhLrqmQASSFqewu35ujIdzNxognHUDLhtn0Bf7VXBbD1LxKJV8y@NHGbolST/ge3k4YG5x8g75pfGcU3eB57SpLO2OCsbdU6k/cia68okMQpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkJB8OiYr9xPSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQTB1cj4dTIJbBFrU0tCpzLBjdocPim/cAOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKnIBLpI27FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGgHFe3LE@rBuvQBzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrQcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiHBk9wQL60QfyKPO6cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNIgJdbC2hr5HorjjXvyZAZRhQQOuFFPLt0B03nGepqmFbr5fiXww1YByB5CJaFUaoOIG3hJKngm/Ure59NCgYz@9PDBPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U@Epfbjoy7EGa7UN7Mm1nZAIagvhvT6wjx5lwKR8s62ZmuNBsjqaWTnM@V6dlbozXdTqORVNBN0VdhJ@6nm7pfBIq8N395Anw@i@On9fkSiSQop@Obkwb5yFXJ8vxeRBdc6T11mB5yOMNU9zMizhuBTs/kcz4HgX0mPr7PqGOAvciugddCtdQfPcSuo9wzyfwyv4sAllDRz9gmQLiPlDc9OY7nquZS3RfK4OF4VQKxxnHRW7PVY3cTyf9/pJzlpxPJCRN1sI5R858P@iSjBjNUp4Hws2hS2GigAoUJtwjujZckcLx3S1yuLL4JNyEMDSsYGnxCDgWXD6DQd9CvgqEFmTR@T5OAzjsMa6SEOnGtTfWBSbUuzafAZ1tLPHQQmyDOhAMbgqyNMKmwvy57yp1Idvx1yw9TlYdkPlpWmW7zle5UaZyuTin8Fn5zTaA2K5Xgw1364JhSvF4GIygUt4gBhWTFvavFTXcpuHRZLtAUaqCp4A4MdMyUnNW3G9dxBWP0NBnYrM5u5PRPgO5BHdMbt5VBkaV9jitwVc18In7PGxnziTg@DAUn7juDoHOsNRsGZVQP1O771g9ia@SQYNhXL7CCvI3KYQ7Of0Nu4bpBps4aRctj4r0NbL/8xrcK1Vavx4gsmM0BATd55xdnKRPL1gDhrxT2Rtb5qTFLuWJ0x76O6Xsq3tLOQ/quvrcE/w9LjW2e/TRJ41Mi0MQRjqufJV4Lc6CLcrAOAOjhHvJwYQ7dSbmhDgB2olgYnlVGTI1o0USyD7A4AlUWZiQXyLM@oVxsShL3wBJNWFgzr35KM2M5KXct/TJxLB5m@PLj@vRzdeJ/GRqlPyOv@hQYRlamQHO1EQ/yGKVPT9@sH90JEPL9RLxfVzBqUB31LtDYFDWFTrAZLTwFXanF2d3ME4SxXYBuhpIH20/PjTqKjR6kD8gdaQdA8NNgGMSF1@64EzrXRSRc2g@gnC/VXdCOAqBJYwklImAVVbm/4XNRS0/nxVo8SnCJKA7cbcCuDWT8tQ238geDDTEt0KQOBdWYbyobSaIim2qSX9D3QiXjkHCIqYRStBoMOktUDkILLJWq8r3AEBYFMDcAWJXFKkqaCd7TQ2qvgbOwNIQBD967R172chI5VZqcxUo2lzmb0Ln5Y/ARQjLoD1jZbKbCerv1zoyzwNfC@SU@wWJ01dOYFTYJjeIfM6Zggcbpojo0P6q5X1Sy7uwoJMhKaGpGCxIQBJi/hEBv82SP1F@kHkwGjkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiGYVMYr4zKQPoEwPXagNI/94wFR7oB6q7@RBPtsUxADMWt5pRZ9OAuvnF7hTqVTMRqPc4emfeLQek9oamdkNY8cYRh7dGJdj4mbUOmxFDTMAw@rrcudN@r06bEiAC17@Avq5EAT6j4vDEykrhzRi@bWV6S8vIlkKVl/eyqNtGBm0ptbQkrlEgXudzrmuqCABNwXFrxXBAMihe1Zk3OyGpw3wKkYGI@AcHHpZVH0q/uP2BLe/X20/vs/f6MH@L9eO0MYKHDmMTS0YejGmpL6ayvLj4oWeqyuWD5BPrVMnRBDpttAdnUXiqRboWE1aFqElyQY/ke4pODXOLRNfADXeEMz4znnK4LBe3UiqxbVbCCZ3XVhr@zH4knR8g8Idj1CAmeCTIMiEenilWDM@BJMRMRGMnZ7poJNU4waM6/34XQy5U9gXG@tRHOM90190w@Zyesd1VD4zvUbqtzVT6Y9RxqfDEI@tbAi7KL0tAYsATvgLwe30bi6@LyAfCd48F4XbDG0KWf0uq1VePbUG0sdksJ73EYdYXRDCq7Fn@uCmP4BvtCwHmumRY8PbIk@dGgo/m4IBfeaShGkmVfQbOmdOfIgwy/fysKdBUBxat1UKpNds7Q8Hq@Pj5IkxS@XV8eeyV2Oj1VzBArfzyrxWTQqsL/D9ZZaheHKHOmWpPUixrXEfNXGhGtBwzVNioOHL@gExo2NHAek7tTS3YXphia@yEewjLBuRtofNp6ZXQfYgTFTi7KqBUNHZMAgkhlsjVskhNuJ6RHZ/mCuQmNwnEQKTatJgNOd4JbRNW3qAwga36qJG2IjjUR21mGq65zhvZZ9GIJoyp@rR7S3K3P1AcRJsrqWDuP42uFgaXIQJx9vaahnpmfQYzViT1ZmdNK1Vrovd4Fg2i86jXdbs/ZMy/HYc3rehKCBC1jgz9UNOopLU7clmgyPmm@gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDY22tT90@0n3//aEULqRQqnoLhQrYH8dW/fdaun6iuCe3VRAdWHRxf2vEeMMQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2cNMiWLKCp/qW5MwLrmc6fPg/XMMHetQGwwd4zmx08DdYYRyCQwTl7PYP09quZtT630YUboGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR81qVMi2jfskYaibz4SSqb02NqbFS0DjsvDbwaP0NQsaHZyrjF2PTn6nHxQE8mhKGeutLhh@Uaxyn0XYjMdEts2vczsosE7UxcN9jFJ2fgeEZGq7HGNjT8VKtLkln9tHNKBuOgy7t9JZyhz5flg6VbuGUlvhzz6D7RomJS3i4QayWz2QyPgMTWXFZstwkSWXDuK9N/lxKmFwWKS/C4iqbGzGuToPQEt2CuJYEaesEewpcLiu2aRuTOT4/kJp2HMf6MjUFRBUPDDsgrUq01famGrvG7viHSNhi6sLDCY9Of92kBR9tfNkS8INC802VHl0S@qDalHDRc4QLUsvWm6dvIgtMt6WCh1txTohvvrXW85L@bIgql@Tijb2Oc6hOx7B0/poVcjfBK8vZG@EtEw1/sRYXd/mS7mIpPnaFKI3ngCyzB1LK0BgZZL2By9d7qCbDf60NNHPwXuc9M4yuMts3uusCjE2gCzY@l9aQI8zSxLFBvprgPj@UUyzcSeq7rqPAwarfSiQfjPSBwfW23EQpFxMWuJuGi3UL4@qpiwrfQdOFaAuFHOubBHSqE2PuBe@VAJ/Mu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50A/oLev28J6fYi1h87QHhpDvm88tK3rHNAeJ1zPzk1Zh1wPhriVbTxe2uIexaflWNaH4BNJIyeUjtNfmad9PPyKJ7e@FFx@0t5/3Tp5p0847UDD2l4zNKYwLnnOxBkbEtnWBbVwooc/19HQYJH6551BulHOB4wE758X/q2y5UB3JuMxvdpja@rRg6JKdGb5Nr6pz7em0KZIxx3Ib51RR/YdZX/fCi2BryYxHXPSHeKhcd6yjYHT6Q7N2zLtK6pQgikfbv0g2RUxYzLpATrLlgnodecytpda1P85vg7WVbo/e8SHtdBwA7@yaoaOjmVLY/2k6/HZUDSxCk4IR3ojP7xdoePvlTdTc7IAGtnLFE7v8mUJNKzLu797Yi1nRWckFmTY31WxtpUSk44MuWRkgOFR1yW7vM8t0sWyWf5Yl6FoKSlHkX0pXwbd/t4fmh00I/O24L7UvpY2La0c5OzhdOBdJ5h8ur4HLBo@1k9b0F7myJQ1jFm67b/WoVmzFDzkCO828FxT48Y1lfyNiyoUTrUk3THh1YYXVN107RyaZY49/mRSf@1SnL@XCWTxq@uFHDfz1cK0XzE9o8@XQNB0G4s4clzciQw8iNTFlXScQUdizhkvTrhsZwBEXbLYInAQdh3bsnKb0OrqD8dM6bOnxkDHvdaPzQlu1lzRKqjJrtpedCvsr091z/z6FEq2rrGhxga@DOlGj/ajbQW8J/rA7D5aqogwkz6C/Z2e/LXU/NHpel2cDU0PdzSFhhsmprDJ8UaMra4NcsOKkFfn7UNlFYsOxI9Brgy9am7dGc/xtNicTDdNq5sTmmX13@tEx3WbwG7MxNl0NJ56/mt1HmjPVHQWenRC7t6ZCcClN0Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTrsCF@YPiwriOG//ctJwB@7yUYcC0AROGzPmKhnMfhudnuCHHtVe0REr7A5c9caJDcnnB3kDdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBGwvDRw48oaA8xqd878tCkI5XY@Tx7bz@4mjyLeM7tLznztTtGmgM9Y1ExQI/VWMv2H2MJzoc1JdyFpXSuo4F3QsM1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtqmIs2AJb6@/@RFMtoaaLf2bVxooI9sYVq7YeBKIzNtYMTW09Hl0IEs8YDrSTqircK3xNlFZU5dItcPnFXyzrM5DCAfLDAB8Z@OHhhdXDa8Ne2nzhPHdmA0GgOhHB0Z/Mz/0kaP1REx2mM81Q746d2azHMCu2YQ4tyGPjY6UL/WwvQhYxEH/ECf6GuGIpobJPkvNN3aVkyrY7ivadIvYl4n0i5n6JExI9lifYPhfVCadLucJcb5uKU@srRi440dx@ZPorYZeKlPbqYqMBTQ48MXymXciL80L7BSPlsu6uEp3yVi9LhSinVldY2OY/HnDXuSbJPvCdBd0/CUx6jjgNwKOSYB9@XdSEOKN9KQhWgEnOyp7tEi/WpRYwFSnX2JLUBD3e06uBLmG27YnRNRTHALmQ739vONAx1A/Awolt6d@spCb8uWNeqM6LFWYIjU5pHRwVNBHdLmMdFn1yuTzwz5qgwiO7pCBQABucJOXWCJZyCNJG8ftpbkqGWsmmN6EKVeu1xOm3Uk2zS6b3WcNXMIX4u56SV/KLPylIxr5qoj3YhmkRWdTrqv7EnLW9eAobEMaTJ0QeZXJjdNbwdqVlash0xHBi4yL6/CrGVdHW9IhXVWr6eHxNU1JF/XH9CSUO8f5w@l3bWcJ4KH/@H9jxUYhNuFXKB6BEjX7Sv4kPmpa/uvD2mBzxxv0jdnh5BvPAWwjpxgsfIQBV68Z6Bpa10hoPbsqcVnHwaRfVejHoljEmliliSLyPXEkAz7VCJFcLPrJXL4oS9lF7X3Toye5OtBwJUG6XFw/isM5r9XLKBGaSNu9lQVjthZIedv/1yF3LOAMgC/5UyksUdvZew9O3h8eCyPPXXl@LQ7xNMR1/i4JcUKWikTmZJ6rbuR9U6@Ha1nehPl/nNV2nt8IGOANfjmKxoSvHBlbum1dt4z0OKq6GulIPQ1JqsZxEfHTx6nFkc0WWJv6DojIxn13nv@PI0nTT5@vtI7Gvsh9I6@M1sb/WBfVZMrmu8Lm1YH11HPFSmtg3RsgDQKjfER18tyK3PVdcZG73g@Nj6BwRMpuPeByRfWFvKpfmoOsBey8lpEUUdlZbmQS0Z2ZoOwbbjhe119nphjpJZdein8tXY7CnIOWcXNruYeblrxv8rFsIy/E@HLRVIz11trVI@wont/34ypqroOz8/1PtQry6@trOUAq9aHLef0A5aSDV94kUInaQKtSjJv3UdelEZAuhV84PS87wjGztptMDcBCJ0LKzv8mWHPdVuitayb2IsKxMZNbTcG@dz4gAWpcIfPKSorX7nGF26pZ4kuGZO3JHzsRqLs7d0/uC3CkY/Lm0N99PQFe6Z7qITk5oDRHBsfkOMFZ/Rawnkr1IC3djm15wIo7UZ4g/Hq/lxhz3W359jz2e2LcHQGFYd2Ui4cwkIbBTIsc2auGqu6fF7r2eptRrelzQ9xOPMlPjiqnMYH9P7b/0xVMxlSPYRvNcOtt9RM0MFZAk36HPXZRb2OD0LS0EW@RQaH5Epp9LExw@0ofDZ4lVC/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Ob/Eo3@OVuSO@aHzqyrJxRbwCYv8GP5eXQ@7FjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVGbqpIOUbClKOUGdfWzotLPrm9Sw@Hl3wXytb67ExcXPjodMxcyvLsNtHJZPsCSpLv@7vb6fQXdreMnD8Ix/cvjq9s6mxMqEn@tvVHkRpTlZ6ARE0hlM6EnHde3mBtAM8r2EPTK5fkd13Jvtku0EwC088r96LYI4fTMfrcwy0ET9JcZWcLwX8FGRm58xj9/Fo3IJNXyH74/641e7reFoWTgyimtFHx7tB6zp8rmiRFBe5@OzZkjMeHp0cPo@4ucZstk7olWbrZMiVPotUnx7nlpLdrr88XYGs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBnNh9/Pw6SUDxbTgZWYHPx7q9mDFdqrCeM6GThis9n81ntI1yZU0P@S62VX5ud4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe0m6jZv12e12rPDY@o7UHYIPYhLMlHKiveMmY5YZBDinK2o7qnCyYn6XsPh8PTXu20mu0Lg7tIk289lZ3g1323HLO2ONQq9A68qCtBq6fGvY64rTqsKJUzt7MhWWvsFTr6oV/vcR/rauS@@sYtSs0AzdE3ERNMP5RV3kYWD7RkreG//h5EPz2sHuWg/P3PXM6uj0wgU2lbg/o3kD@rgI0bw@GH/s4GTqufXvQoDlVKveND8zExgeHHM27zgfkodPv3x5o33NuD/Rkak1MlFlWB33qTC3UILDKb98drHSvb9ebTbkir/NEbere0E2u98d9kc7UAxnIDIlnGFF6bU6WHIM2E3VD5e6GLdtO8grcjx32NVTjvgIVbz@wjj5@uC7c8oLNFJf46UTwwriyM/PD6EDLoh8y8NK@KiquvIEfmffk4GsTiYQNRU4uf9orev4f1X0nNlHd7Sad9YewFxdswz9fDx5icGLf1yiAWjFNe2qgSgD@wZ9JbROSqdXUfJnt4Le0KkzNUJr4icAyVz4YJNZgm@f@aflKRb1kGzUmVkTm6ysIdYlzfdgAGDX5QqGYdKKyzQn4bAZn7Rl92oVdMJoilLqoMBVsshLVOlL1tRFAnjbPnx08239@vHv84nkj07r0tRUEpbBtSC3QiXIn2xOh8D7eQPTg2vFJS4YFydFnZ3Bq0QvKxfBTVstFqy0VbVEocQfjbJ7btqKQwgZFuoT8SSJPjXxxAAUnDjsoMVWQr6ujwnUnkAoIqCMOWqQ0odIqLLMq4bEObPSm7ftf/fIb@eLXASv4fUBM2FdoDi144Dg9P0XPYLdfQYoPdw8evzjaZ0EGF63mzOxNhrVynuu750pkoJ76Ju1grbG4HyUOdVWrxR/GATFxOc4qpGKDdM1DQ4dgAXZQOYcfe4slNgk@YDAeVoryn7@hXMZlPIyRhLDxIFNxSBbaPDWUjY0NdgyNhD04Ovhk/4hh/vcfkDOiCEGwYzzf/2c/7vGvtQT6t4IvI7oj4nlJf5EQ1fERKL5Y6OZAnFPfHa//PiJ9HYU0YISfZQm/KyUI9NUeaLdnpDrzilrFJGk6499z9LVeBglREwq@8IDrfqjB0vXYqemZqH8D89BHhZLLjR23CpISVZnt4scf8ROTOn06CLI@tSdcaZuvuikGLU0OaU6abVJm@YeGxEjA@PYGNPaOAeIQ82wTCPKkwl5DS8S1tQrXzyJJ9fi1KAHoCpkkZKEjAa9poPSUpqu8/7V/ogyqDMwTMH/HN88y98H2K76tD@Zf5eaXCja06xorF3mJZgi1zPol4BkJ8Y@4j3zz0uY6cRaIQ8WaAWFl5giq6ZSwjsF5CvwpAT1ewEk0PoFKg@YGNebrwuHpGW4rgWpuK4qCTQpFdJnGFWPGtwVfUXdbyBdyqgKZlE4DgPR9igHqO@AAk8kKdBPh1BzXXoHYt729zUScpzNqhSqvWWXTfpkVX4UZ3YSwwtkQM9dgEAeiLGKAX92PBqNPSk1iVKRecTWOhKvnwLBE/jh8od32ESGyBCCL48jADx7M8POoE@BefbXNHfygaOTbRZs@IEmFMYlMSVHwtcg8dSbQfKCTLr5OxrXI4LZ4PgSiPlSPfzSYtCVje5Sv96yF8oPgI0l@X5ORBnBQ2czV0TRat@KnCOI5gqiIq5pv4yVrTpp2S@Ftk0Ez/eGKxmyD@ZeVwZo2y8u9e11XbuKqpltEFrv33HZwQvIhFIYlNEXLKmohuShSLreySH6J/GSgOKiQ6wKSAzIFJKNrmK@dsbe7t3/w8eGz59f0wVLI@NVgQPfr26mmJKcbrdAQjxZruUruP1SeP7n/MKiIRaYLEWoMhN8viXpTSRbrDAhycW7tatFW5fBq6dbn@FOu2eJqfrPaTVmjSNfyoWa@RLp0dkR6SCdAryaulVZhK5@/KUsLeEoE9B4/vn8tq4nk@WWjBdKAHYtfbwkrOsLLmLyFnQBMTW9rU8HGfr1wWLDwc97H@JFEL9oXs6v7oriZRXWDqD1k4pwsFDL6DhGPSHmDZIBECrISBF3b@w45k75QG6rxz41zPYVRLWyRDBcyN2E8Auo4@HI5UpGF0mNf3@9Q94aW2REC7Xdc72@gnjRU@cs11yWSgv/pHJ5wwv@W@awyk2mjaCKJ1I5gpdlNKoQDeEkBOjRyd8@m3pA9c8b8Uwq0IeiBEZiOHCC/D6Z8AtFgH09HEK5PryODFmeBcksQGTAZD7PKeSmgEr4G4VkKdTRDeg3UI@wXXB718olZUh4as545ANqeSKaBot1R1RYLtQxjoUmrsB0Xqc4WtXBjV/wIlTJE0f6lVE3PFhnQG7ps2j1jloifxZOVFqSP7vGzT0/jSXFVWyKV174O6N5V3ddh9ovqzZREn/i9M1AsvYpalMvXqQS4XQXMdTAG33Erl@WhJ9B3OWvIuT@fuI/BCGxEoj/Sxywxtbn@SpmRNdFM2GlS7CfVuW5cm6VSJFDBizxkRjH7ZOLjd0K35yyh1PDTreDq2T18vTXHrKHKcgvMlEiSbeL3FfeA40KNrkkBhGCIUiGwNWxCIGZAjngnkXkDhzjoD2HhRVpAV3jT5@ZoDctBnFCpWf0ui3wvc5lzFMvlil@hy1SxzKD1XSeHsgJgr9G5gK8H7PqqrQBnIP7KQmxByK9TvBilG@MZeeTrxILsxCL6rANVWQxgLbRNd4cu3ol9G/oK8AeVyovjh@1SUhFZqFtr4Jo9XGPln2QIRTz/I1rQTZWloPEql@g@wmioxbTNlXehMs2H1GHEKyQ1FkWDrwk6EJa9RdtU1RtbvR/RrwUImcMBwD@D3A7AoebZYPJ1hd9qYv@zn8WQ2UhsqupJ2z1NxfOZKjzUap7l2Z3NpiRtNjK1e5s6SFGTN7MmyOTKVu7BqTHs9w4GSlMUWZblFGXr/Pw8/nDrmfkyzwpSz9QKb2bzy2wh@2Z2mVVLb07GaqEhv5m1xFItfdJiz5599q79LinOTudvxGZCi@0dXohqDkX@WKXMzncK2dhJGcRPSJexE/YWrpM@wz@Z3/YiZh3NnT6IsHGRxZpNwLgqFkVFacRb8Cdx/xVcXPBv1OW6vNN69y7Z0PXJbM5M0xx7vR7czhA4SC35nIG8fBcoPY@gsCa9SYLCazTrX59PyDM22zUGg@m@XtfweLp8r12dm9OHkyeffxpcL/B6exSJ9tb/oHMqlZCkxop5ikpbz8fw09B/9pONy/T5s/b2n31zpBgb@DrE13cun6D5uZq/s7Fx5/79XC6taRo3P/v82S/u7u7mHqTzzxr5nZyU2dj@0z/Z2NC0bU3ZaHme2oo3Tk4@E7VMTpT/7Efx9rNnX/e8evb//Ma7uoqPIjxOWRHoBFxZpoIRnyW4VeSxPvSKvY1BK1djc/q1Y4H7@QZT6zvF//K9wzexSayuKZ@68J7E3sQKpRg3ggFs2cB2GqvHtjFY4TI2V2q1GhiL/@XfQvz6xwAHfebb8KjnA1iFeawu1SjKRaxeAIOqaZDu//2Nb0RyyMlEjdi44LrHGnCJuaIm7rTg2qJrW0CdpVJGUYJw9mQ4MRymlu6qd9FiggVetoEffzAmzZhayjF2eI@xo0YqlWrJbQku@SVNEimqqjVV9S6QA@nOVq0mbTGulTWbzd9FzfJJmtIaODBiGnc//Ye4Yqscqz83uCMhVti49@pBvQ5lytazW/UUXX5Hoj5VLImOc09kafYqDiJIo/XqMeOqpOtipqSJ6XT6XpvsM8SVNAtbEl78GYuFLthl2VW3pSgQxHeNfflwsX28/vx/@/Pv//n36Pd9uv8DKnW1e2Zf2YJAp9Al6nDdq1S69bpYd8XzJtrr0I4ylVKlpLQvm4ktoECtI6ZmPrqI57Px5/4H5hlrJik2XJRs3U8e7fXYwrnOXepRN9@DByYH5peCDEtYI3OItWvhYGj1t79LjdN6S0KGqCY11EK@JfFY9eAqs8Y9qCZRK5bFVl3La4fsXnvGLzbc9JgTA8mwEODRz299UbZ66LOw1aNOsXoQrb4I82XDhfkVYo2G0jJoQAjc2L2NykapUqhoSru@/oKmGbVSUMMwnnmx01h4cczGFgiNhU3zqltQFaGFBS2YfZlwUFnhZLe29mJUS9mCKlZ9k9ZmYhUaiZaVtEFbzKhi2Ntwfh@uDfjRH67Qis8NcvGdKcj1a4NV1C0tq@TvFPY1HF9vuaIDhQDjBOt2Op233Q5wHbre0bu6OtGn@kyf65POtDPrTLrTLjBNV2f0s07eKTkzNqO/LMWyeXUzdpdWeVT8Z4tatpDLFgvZoqqVytlCOVsqayVwyWaLGa2Uz2rgWMoWitkiOBazpVK2iGNctlDIlrVsOSvE3jU22BEnZy2WCq5m6tbrhSy3fSMZHLwlyZnFhNg/wFVXNZVtwUCXgQdwd2QE4Rt/qiqwGHBs5613W413W9DT66ltorKtuuTnEl5y@14rJV1eNsBcrfr/7XporNLFTVC41mUqtf2yDmzMy3ojBSBf@iBliRFQuV1vbZNPmJifmu@93QJGSEptN7Zrzh7dMvU0KZ5z4gXnXgsAby9l9t69lAymewCgvgkdO5lKbUrSBg6yDX/QgcCteiooFeYhAWzH@fnPeYPECOTgcvuyftnYvrzc3ob/Nj0v/Te4Xm5f@9Nrca0Js/BvIY1qNpR6U2n6VKcFdlmpo4usNMFQhzeEa2S1UquBBrjk1n@bfzm9eIYumOWWDLkWYltsK4a6SrOxLSH26v0X/wvezfdf/D4yngx@RkWInSN9ULZQbC1z6RUezH5isyf8ssGMd2BFF3R4UkdHmz9sXNlSlFcyq/DFg4RaKiRlHMnbTr@N6k9k9gqCLpEXJJ1M1EoFsZ1S5xqLbYuFItHNX7h2xePxf/RKKxfjfMYH9Xe88jzvSSSXi3xC4KqWUSX1os4/UcG/JvQLq65/9AvrLiF2UWZGBfCTYBwxQgzaUUxRJAlGvvr2CA944JqLhOLtae0z6cWuhPMx@oRW1Lp8rqF2sF8rl@t8uWjzGfWarQdb8FThv78BxWDNPoRt9mvdEXDSzX42rzXxewYxqfMGf4/f4o8dd/F39AZ/7Pgt/o4m@GNPOvg7foO/3Q7@jkf4u/8Gf0/e4u/FAH/Nr2SzalXcPCfMpNSyerk5EwlD1dhOvfmViTuvWIbdMHst/1Nd2VyZJWPNrxizrjGeVLhjP/7T737zm/FaLS7F6QNIOdVxmZqMMQyIX3EF2lGFmoDiefHqvfhXGiTq58utBvq3wEuI1dimuqlmrEw3o3bUDhhMlnFZZpgZqj2VRKKMwTLzzJxlRo7aA5MBvwyYzEyfZQYsY2dsCAa@YJq0MxM09eE1gF8fALnwM3E/c0fNdBkkZKHYRN9WVdsYM3PRbgoNFmfiKwNkWlmVM3LBbOEXqRriq1dNZaullUtMxjYntxuvmvGW2BTxKwVaOcc6c2Oj@UoEFiAj8raJLizmeSAoV2NKs6lwNAKGCMuXl@32/tMH7baCo1TziXO4@B8ejqLWG/@jQ@fJoTNy4H94eAg9y6in7qWAft@7VwN67r92YvXqTrNCo0IwMsSU7Z1mPSuhuZACYq@hW@pLXguI8K5vNIX4GQgqZyDjVBMg6ZxVT6vVMzJ8yq1gaKMZHcP/mW/w3wShGspJZ3CdEliyofHs02Zo4gbl0zNw@pSBfBf@QZCMWv8r/M3/tv5PXrAkSzRaycT55XaCriT@ksnzy/NL/1lPJhK@JbENP3QAO0Y5v6yjkQKdg6mRSLaSl5fcDZ6J5DYHWIdktusUdxEORo1YmCQlyx@J/7pvSNq/mvEq8Ndchs9nqB/FxCrTF/t3ms1ZJpOsdoIPsOBqtH5BmySSVfr65manobb@9Ef0kZ2dJAXK56pVdYtxi5bTqtVcYCuWqtVSYNlMJMrXr3pmRy2AnJPLJZPVKlh2ArAZsELcBnuXYjXWhGfr7l2eSEm7uAhgZnOFVAb3TVWrQUp5SNbw9K5PkM8PDun7NEBq8jH8MBQnJYkMfd0Kv6AYFyvi3buJnoGb5ns7u8m7d7Vy5uIidBmPwUldcmq3e6bbbqN79uJCbIu036acB3umdHGhZsopNZ503MRT/PQmJJWQVHZHq1OqZSDzWq4I3n4G8tvbhVy9XsiBS6EUT@LaPSfxkN@4GK@KsXMqg1oqcgooVtE5ug8J@jKOE@z8MkYVynL5ZAIIaRJYxMsY/lykuXw4yueTgJlLkYdUy2UeNMlyhUQpVfZ/tQ2Q/oEH4j9k5LKp3FZx6x6wxPjzZqsupMnVc6OmXtbOjQrO3l9Wu/5HzFHHi3H3brYMKCplqk2h3X6we7zbbtdgLEM@Ch7oSNRdQNU3brxSvUf1qpbyDCqQO0pxGBJYCbCsaFt5tYRYEcw@6mwCHAhcDNtgG4JGb3wIZY6qDXAE8QZS68HFeqzDBnixAUqFzGQWXcxi3J@e3W4YyOGX7xtaKS4JjoGLEV6C3@2yvE3CqP3s8e7e/nFa25ZYTHu4u5fWnr@4H1PRml/YyTuL9qP93QeHLyDCs8f7u8/3Pzr4ZP/FM3D32NniCqi8/1y8o6YV9jP2qfDafasbhm5MDaN9Np2evWGvTbNtQu1ZUyiUM3CZZ7ShLGN9Ua4q3F3T01@/1t0xXez9D7/9/of/3fvf@e773/n2@9/5/k@/@P634f4x3N/l7@/@m3Ienz/94p/97vvf/h1w/A9w/xHcP/npF7/xDX6T/Y/h/k8Rtz/270g4fgsA61d@@sX3fvTTL371B3D/S//@wfX7136y@v7@t9bfGO97v3tzmO/@W7h/j8MKwn73t7kbvq@F/20e7ld/8P5f/Dv@/1P/h8bfef8v/hgfvuWf/uBP/9P7b/57TSv96b9@/63vvf/WN99/6zvvv/WPtfe/8a/VTPTxu@@//wd/9Ye/91d/@D/S/8f0/L0P@b//wT/9i//1L/73v/hD//4J3P8OTD/5i38PXeVv/@CH@P/eH/ztH/0Q///zv/rbP/j1v/2V/4kMv8kN/8@//Df8@de/9h//5re@81c/@cbf/PpP/uY3/@Cv/o9f/b9@4z/@9X//@3/9T76Jjr/5k7/6o1/5y29@@y@/9c//8ptfrHl@@8bnFx/g/sU/gMuH5/ND4HxIub6syxc/V37@PthYpALtBFr3L7//jV@CBv4vGHv/7R/jcUi41/x/rKkU5sfc9v8Bg3a9zOiTARPcv/7@299FFP0PgCL4h/j6TmhZ8uGW7ywsgNbfWhHpl3/6xT//EdliRqVOy0E4WJe0UmoLBJqtctkfsP2VIojyS8vQQgB@St9BCrXk9x2kbe9/@I33P/rH73/4m@9/@Cs4Wku5cno3Lam3LLNBwPwHhMOAhQ8JhwE/g/TbKZpyk1KfgW3js3wpa9t29bPPPhPaFwqeu713wT6DH/ssuBj3wnO5vlfgh@54UJeBe@PVqxauzUbcFJUDVzT@9r1w6zykJGl3UjuKqnEv40LZ5LFYFRyypWwzknWl39@qwI/Bo1LZOk9LO01g@ijqpWAERVJ9qBsKU/V0diurQ0Alx8Oxin0vk0sVt3QdROAUwk0Rz7MV8GD5LJul/CRnjK9ToTsEmm2RcYZPckXvmYAP@hcZK7EsYzb/VwWWoslrvoSSWhjJ4Mfzk@BGIQ/JpGbh6hgxhYxzZVvchRa@Kd1cmWEJZrPUDKRtMEAKKfC6D3x/rZbCiDWeRbDywtRLjLKSStWg3Bibx0m3Swhidp@gQMxa6oi1t2ozHjGF8OoBOlICOh2JqiamSrUHkGBt9oAhLAROYF@9qtVLtVkdwb3j2EnNUvcpTwislprV34G9RjAhnhB78A6yUqqlUvUSJoiF5NWTbvNKylPhqOwplvLrAN54fmHnHmN3RLUk8lWPDUQYD43P1CI0BoTg4N9MbfnFoX9gpHuLEL5BSfmpMO6/QzzxDmeTMQDAlSRZlhncuKFgh90D7xkHlaJk4ZXiEFLUIqgFhA4MJ6JSQorqN0UWSD9W2/rSFwLDwmxubgqxupgVD2VCnaIw96RChzlwfyPKMRUmFsoiOht0siXIC8SvUvqbcVwpjDMOmN1J8fvevS12B4pJ74WbwKRU1sk5MQ5lO5USNYBfd1LCS5B/BGinBOhCkGc1WplMCek0Y3Ithn7s8PDQzwQ5vKwJKWjmWlZFO66PTafTGMSQ5bScTvtvmd7kIPsGmXz9t7yJyD1zzYnBNC1XBTGtytCJRWUqFWRtdHz37h3UCm0YqxyAlMv8vWNarkSe4MDVHlnWPDgCpeXKAp8CYGohx1iCpnrhSjI865OAhpQU@EEDno3gSsS1UilOIQH/cmIr2ExYUJEC8ENVdAqW5YtLVshN1IrTgnxiOFbHkgUXF1ZL@WTguXfI9g6fPNl/ejxutZiA30CdToz22HW6hucl0G/36QN@JkUrF5KxRgOxclzRkCIJ@5UMNtTUwYOjg@cVxrHk11mCylGllWUfL2VViI3Hn27H/L1XIn7I0hGf47OyQEVCKwO1TMbqQqxroAiEWwZQNK@yqvDEG9x3ZiyRSYtiWi2gCJrEBVLIxy86U4ZqlrlOJuiEeFJF3t4mDAj1c4nWXNAI1VsQ6nV/1yJThfrz/WOIcHzIVC0jC/XP2EzGBKVLoW7VLMMeTIabuP1PbGbESJk2G5k0/rRsFp5qrpBW88XWxoZ1LmGaTarlc9zHeQnWcwmL8VW4mPBVgX0VnOCCNHBzJvN3xh4cVv3tiajQMMH3KIpqHvplUsAZeA5OGEevKnSH5RUsIbbx@ecTVq@D5C8dPBRiQF6GLNihJ5k9eShTNfemrkG@A8Z65icmfqFU7pne2NLn0NcAG7HLy8s@QDp4yLS6RlYeo4fPyy65dMB8OdOFmF2p1N6puaJwtFupvMtqmgAOwpaCWwA3oAHQToothf@qHiSSzZYUIG2qKMIrm80K1HyFiiEw2i3zLlOrSbwNZnMqbZYR8KM3@qy2WP72w87uLMJmMzws@oAHG0xclgn8itzPtxUEsgHScH8gfWK96vfmzN27WZxeyeYy4TwKlZhdQt1sZnNZxDiev2rFckV/dUcUxVZMsIwJ69XAHGvCg08VampMZGhDKpMtZYRYI9YQ/v9@@QtY2@N6NqNuK2Mw6mDMbSs6GDtgzG8rHTCaYCxvKyYYp/WsmtlWpnWBCdtcFzJDVUs1cWLMUPU6dxPrnmH1ZTyWVRMpAU3c9r8tUA8i1nu1ntOd4o6Yak82bdtwUTECj5DLiVXHRi2dNdTXQ6okWCJ5LgxqZ6S@QTBqAxkVP7m2bgk9ueP05rI3mVt4wMly3FocGNt44LGAbgDHg9N5O9lsrtJgLXnsjHcELV9MNdQMDFV4q6W0lt4wdorFSk/uWobu7uQr@VK6h2en/FW9nXymMpA/e/L40WQyPjLoQNVOrgwRUFUiKjXbKVXy@VajIYqpBiXTws/Cc7ombWwAMTD0ngRvXPPzJK3Ugsg9063V4vGdrKpJaiWbKV0KC8QhzrGEdQGjprBkacT7uU86KrZjA5WqpPW0eU5YqPT7/cut89TCIujnErcBfi4lPd05D61VKRKuwqZpyVx4goveB3Sf@8uZFVHLl8Rqo7qwFwtitXUp3BsZPVPHc1TNzPn1WAWg5hxqDBJqMuGy4jrOpNIx@o5rLAJm1UIQkGfoeoCceBkm18xgiufXkytEAs3Or0PJ5cXLMFaQLeHyEvDOkQ1o9xVd12m/cUMt51r7QLug@WwHOrAxWOzlSyG2dfRJtl6Hqj7PFbVcPpfXsoVCvqjBQFXOFUC8y6iZQiavaQAlVy6Vi5fQrhXlXYw@ccn2zoP2XqGPfCT0CtdS22ix5LunpnVeyko8H4lk9fIy9k6I3Tn6RIORde2VgNH6E02q17L5MpiyaNKykGEmaJqkZaWsKqlZ/N9i0PD/4eE1@Gv4hFhZTThG1VVPYbwFHsFmj1EFzsRhxw5@BG3A7hvdNSH2hjptBt9zHc/7e4S5r9sn3OuByfVFh16PdPwSpDcyJ8M1IV6MR6j1ynD/wSDsjzqQQSSHPMB9eLiW46wKUGQvnq0p5ZPwCw2ADP6JBgh@dPDRo@PI@3h/d@@RUGD3D58@uPLK@4Hy7PH@w@PQWuS@QdR8COIX9x8/vmr1X7nDF0f9qePiLTw8fJFbPEInPGss5OBaDhQ6ExD/gVbiSIEVAZEvXwwMqoAnVO6CGH7XN@YLC2MGjZ/yg9SmF56Y4GfqK8JxcLpaZ0hpOwbrcuVmOC9Aikd9mUEtlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlu4yp9/fAMehjidFDeSELQtbIiZ95rhW78zsGRvCEzyUWgaBok@ZEB4BkNG0S3ozgAtCNdYwqtkMV9o61tRg0zFb6wgvdEKjaw6GMAafOUEAoaPrDO4ve0F8I3pNbnaY8DTI7ZqPdT24ANJjKS@Ke6L4SJ/oVdcovqx6mUrlmTuG4Vj3Bsb@DFosewE9SHfn6VI6K05ksfCQye3Yyy1ta4DrN5YzRgHGGzeA49/JlRqtneZf/9aP/@5Pfn1QA2rTzOxl8jj7tL3z5HHOmYwr3lyv2JwpVKonlZfsHatX41I8m68A@QMWmREX7HPKMslMWrmUL5WzWildKpdyebWQz6dVLQ3yabEMEkdGLamFUr6spku5MnAquTL45stFn89WAsZa2aoAWLuLn73fJrFLHoJ8xVdf2duEnmQxPbRPmWhAHFFAkXhCJ/O3zBoMskzNsGyRAUSddVns4cO9zMOHongfLbh7ZS8jij205EuZTPG@KBrks1dCrkt0eJwSKhAVJ9ySydyHaphyAPjtDVEcomW/gJOKomiiZW/34UNMp48WDeNDsBPuwy1WYClCMBstwP4TgDchNAi2y9PJUUb30YJJos9D7rMHfqL4UZAd9DniwTiAR0FJd3dF8YBbdnfRZ4@KnecZ/RpadukSRRcs0D1EcQCGgQsdUxQ7YMROIopdMHXnOriNwISfZ7AnuijOOXoQQaI4o9B690QU24E7JvOJn5s8YrdCFpWX@h5ZyvgTRS3INAbLhpasKOZCSw7K9ujRJ/pw0jMG/Jq7/N2Fkj56lNXN2XT/YeejjzqDQced7@5/dIRee3uPgGOZT93OoONH7LThciDW3iNNPxnNr15Q6oN2u6JbK72@1m7ndPuKV3veNjCHEOsN5My/BpjQqL0HXnuP2vf0VavnBLCN9GEE7w5e90fwvq93uFdwkRe9Z52OWMXmryjNhIAyBS6DY3c8AXprp0d613WqaJ/VWCaNbM28Uci0quTBRiAbZKqX6N9P4FPHmajk@bwxq2VatVmtqPHtV/2E2JxpeVNMb4x21HK@sqHvqFouNaugchCnH2dxSd1hCfXu1luWeJrc0UBOEJs7O5LYUFs7mlqqFIovt6aimKzgcydbrLxNZOIZxvCRbBRbO8V8JEaxmNIVrVIsArcGOJnAoN/B@Z52InFm6CfJJOaWZh@gCFRWNqdymtV@Ypae1Xi@2DxZndXUKldLzjLXgPXwGxjT7sRxOcgBgJvtZCq45SIhquWSCBlQlEQyGRI9BUyLjbGffv345Pj4M2IL6/7EyDPXQOpV9a0fPdqTDw4DG369Qn6I3KrjyntItZZ8ONsaOB2DnCI/goEWZL7ADQ9huo4l79OGQmB5A49AgZbsa5KWjx8twXk@dM54yqjDokrqSO2uwfDjHmaP6bU6mPQeS1CumJ48oyG@Xa/X2rURqXmAIgaxvsboyxcLMAcez3uoWYOin@PBRN@jXctcVju1WWwGcNo1JqmvRk7vlZbqVnv4TY/7tfsYudqGd6dq1AzXdVwRJG6x2t@xa1Pb0/vGM8NFnTEHh5vAcOBpxUSfGclN1tzH0HsozVxKdZfZi5w9nY4SulTvJJedcNIvdEDkJL4eFPqcDtC2a6J4We3XWOIlBH0DdneTJXry/eROrgp4us/aSXDKvOq/6jONFXJVkkYSCAu6EuEHy62zZK3@NXhx2CeVCuTGr@gTgIqJAWCzRx4QemxeVrs1iyUkNmNJQlKuOqg1MPoFPrYlUWxJUuOiJdQl6VOhDv21Oo/pNW/aoc9BsUxH1TKF6gzc1GKuOoTq1V/Oqm5tPHWNqgVWf66QnxXWq4BUwB2AeXuReP9L30huS/kad6sSqAtkB9pyuzar2qhgFhpGLVsDj1Qjl0mDnA@PYhrGfK2QVgvpbDqXloroCgN@Op8GR5CDgP1IWAmRMTGdmWVkNa0aajqReWX2XiXTJwlgbAhpLJmeOPv2dMTABaoK2yZZ4Q3oSWlbFshnPYfp2xI1ViAZVSwYYH3IxmZ6iKCODN2iGMmkxLJbCWszgWE2j6fj/UarUtmfjb8OXgnpzU4hVcyk3iaT1cRGsuYZb4R6VagjeaFSjzeg5frTqMybjhpQy2BSi1ql0ehgEYuZdDaThdKZ7YvBtlgXW@nMRkGFKrpkRDYYpxvRmUXkeBZu4zby55YBVaeWtaog0zRftqRJZSW/lc/wqUYeUxj75A0xyRJNMTgXn4jHi1o8noxXcVVkQ/RntYGmET2LA3WN31V3RGDGxIpY1jDAgjTS0edMkDtgxy4F5BlZDsTfc@Hy/HK7LnxFeI4HWre1l/grvnyye4i/r4BTGayll09eHL44fCgwhXa4AhNa3ajK1XYVLJJcvyfEKowBJW36SruUDca@7N7Z1Hb9JX838UwFwBVIaXyDtWhPm2GibMc@QYUQOywOZdDdUUPTsq2GVoSxD6hpEFTT1CquGcXw1IZch8qYnUP@tlN1PEv5NTaf6ykpmBC4y9ggtVnhhwK1ubaFH5WXWOz0ZKNe3krFn1WyqfiDeDYXO4VK2ayn1Hk8tZXC1VwlpWZO2EZpK5XPb93JbsWPUpXSIF1RU/jU4FmJM2kjdq@dxvW9spcUqBZY7MqkxG5td3C0W2X1kjZXqrt71djLtlgqZvn5xLqWojOcbDM4ClpHxWQvcc69KeDG/njsPM5i8Uv4CbF7dJpU46dJWSw8T4oL4P6yUDZXYMlYOenbiuWYlwjXZL4SvxeL49JHxfPexajhBIf1vvZKgzYbs53AAQQ7nHSDMTWfx/WBmPJq7H2ulbJPDg7tB@5DQ4g1Ny42HFytYYvdje/sj7/O2BiQGmfNWmxWy/nb6tV6XVK3NdSfV2QVGDb6akHKXNR5x6iTR0EDn/e/9IPcbLsEdi2jgl3T8imtXle3NCjY@P0Xv4@akM73P9l9zOI4x/93f/Ijrfh3f/KvaL9e/JLm/bVsMQYh0agWirHz8/H5@SVc3C8fa8WubVNoAX4UVS8Xt2QojVLSwdBWYhyPwCgV1WTMk2L@psxCXkokVEVLbmVLmST4XPiazhJapgTWYOmLnMRCXkzG9o/MvKbe296Bku1kc1p1A@pSDU8Gs/C3bXhlFCOfvLpgDCzdem8wMDUyKQqrvJO23zFpm73DVad30gZ7VavjNgsVzxMHqzJbeL4SlzLj9ZSyFWcgYLF647J62UrRsg6Jqy@37OYVPDQ38FzMstOWDT9jy6OfYZCVHDywBjZj67UnJraSitLridcn57YNlq9DU9lSFqee2VawWMN/ktRMvv@l39C0wt/9ya9dtC/an2kgpJbLBVWL/exn21N76hm9@s8AwA36bwJBk3hNVFSDhlBAZVxprenHCg1yF2TjqY3MOA8fiKsooDJgZMyBbfRIXBVOkfmimm1zFYy9BAXbQvUYaWLmSeVZsioIAdfLmXV30E0TDLaFmpYbraRwLnwVvWBsZ8DwV4WvLkCBwwhGc6fb9qypO6ZzRQmKp7bS7C5EgRS@iuotN0ithz8wSEAhla3rUXmWPcIaMWpsZHgeKsuEMU34KkTx1dFbczbWUQMNhjRtGIlkDEL5JI9eA9JuQdoWj9Am1wSVngdIM547HskGhl74KvAmhAUTWBZmbkOAKpCVrwICoAwJH7DZYtssm2TnZipVXWjivMQjDqhjVA@0XwgYDaH1UNtKELmK4cAJBAn8ADK2C7@GgWOMOAZAOAy@UaEGoghGJxtygaSe5oNBASxSBZegorG7dxe5qtXMXpJRiRD@iTnGyTaqB3t1XgFYIMbd6VXENEMdp9XANWx2gPEUZRdancSVm1YjUZmI1ktBgP8HN1pskVeqijyqWAC/vniv6ALKIDKinddhl23XmKoVkyzMfBfy3qVMkQ6CUDZtzu7I2meB5yXk8Gex4PNiQLSOoxOYfru9qv6EAec@xW87oRI8Tgx8tSVczR0Sv4NJEDuMBUUxLQrdN12QmmgHRaBhM5FVkxhtoZGU8kGHELQcw7MA@SS@KBaGZvDWUVOkn84GabjqOlCh3tixSbUkqb7CgxjQIoBG@Vr5eLan9hl@C9CvG4oczZFHGvmw5WOOSVWmgzqEKC7uSOi4IF0HuEkzYyCz7qjHtDJLUEMj7YF2CC5JkSjDHWC@EccdyxhBlp4bBp3u8yqKMgCGbNohFYpPTGhXw4cmjEC2pzzgCFbOzBNTOUal3JLTx0OAXCFNDHk47H5884OvrtBynBNmmScGn5dOLKnz8RiIH8BBpwGzixsQW8FtOFo2jbMgapqHgrsIryI3ltKRuBuJefL6O6tuJNpYoxc03phQK5ZxqtsR/NJ1Ifhytzf3AoVgpNYK7HJIcg1fFVAtjko@Qh1Xgq/arEZatWRc7xgnxJgYqARDozB2jVOGErSAYwwQzW6gXAd7MZT2qzQAUN@DnoWaQiduBVVCQU7cXqILXc8n8Da7w7KagAG5vjZftxrAwKqvLUMHP4iK5fAmPagYmSb5ka5A7xz1wA@VkfjND@MHrRvNpMV10bzZhg8OBx1Kq8Z4twgs@YgFewe2Zyr6BngWIIcrcrKREFMANiUmRQ46jH81Om/tAtGSCrsOKc0Qgo9qgEKsgo4kB1VBRj7aJ4DHfd3jX3bx9YienZ3JpNx26pqy4eGH7DzH1i1lPDCBI3aUiTEa@58MN7vKOIC7MEn8@5XyeDjemSFfWyvfnfO3IPS9mr83KRHve3EcHE/xO22DESnCQw10HjWohyZ947Gb8LdK8fantdLnQfurYPuTSvFLBMIYgpml5@luGoClO92TdP@sV/U9TqlDAnCoRSNwRJXTbmAZeYHJHPfDEM4E6Wjo1bFOaNUYIIl8uniRNC9hEHIeWH372JxBJNs4Y7uuq88T5J/E0NiAE3Nie9gchn3yASNqvT/n@o/NWWPeWoo@C6PDoBbumXBRy51wfjNQrgwb/Wfcfwb@M@4/WyQaJNuYtThLhk6XWBxs9agcNQiJYOZBmEuuOHrhQ5CBH2cqB4Eh50tul3B3axQ7wDe3QT3WgoYBbWIMCDcSSuNls9Fs2Z5xttVKKQNo7CIhAmocQDdahNOzXmhG7Fun1tjxlpxs1IkLo5Kfb3TqDv3WwNsKljGsIGoYHF8mqjEdjPzNHZwh8AsMEJAPA09kDXYnCTNZDbWvkyc0nIa4wDHPWMPPTIu4L9/LdwN2iaOeIzYKqBUBhO5hkSCb4MOCnsM/WxpQh09dB8IEYSX60uII1enFW3HA5JWuwmlNlSopkitJCrIJaEd2tXa1KIE/VEXjilekmJd@/Uezv/Gls9@HfrE699Rg@YBRFaJdBTdiAgvhdxfCKqvXIvUKOVC2dMtwYeTa5/ypP1pDMltKIGbwdLAI3pk56Q4TkcrvJnn90EFU0RYrYVOY12pQxHmNd0veLwKUcoSH0Tw/2jxoCH58TkAARmZlNMOPNotGm9VqnHCw2ZpoZ5FMziiTMx6Fh56tyWTLjwbS00EwvGD1tIA7xZ2iIsBT@TAKbNBYZJ5@auAS/GtU9YlLFH6aC5pDrcBvQ8hiYzvrtlam3ohkOkK0rgDAhngNQI9/Ab0iXCV4qhTaQhrFURnQKG7zmwGnFdDAiARXuTrsRNjISAYGhl9M0TgAfVdMNQRRpWlm/GX4LaYDx@BWrztmlkOqy46Z9JXfP4hjCzEb6aAR7kPN5JAgoyTzwvb1yEZ5jhjbnYKAA1xd58xhiRXMNrgrUz@q0rGcjjLScSsNfheZu8rjeTKQH3Chht0bOxN94uRyFS40mdTsVqXPZQZzYDv4ObWISnzg9XqO4dnxCVRq1xnYpmekGWorPTF8scPwP@4hRPlk3@h4guBv6uJiLILm7QpZ3XbbtM1Ju53AvZLJSrhjnLZO/r/dfW9bG7my52v8KRRDhu6k/Y8EkpiYiQGT@EwCuUCSkyWMp7Hb4ImxPW7zx5PkPPfeF/sFdt/vR9ivcr/DfbWf4mz9qiS12jaGzJzds8/mmcHdLalUKpVKJalUBfZcXs5g/UtPTnkSTxro3sDrn/waNUf@7TAR30EXO@w0P3t7A50I7xtVRTKsSfo/pZ6RBqPifrJyZN/xUKVPRh4HNDnrn/dPSeu7iPPYh81MgK8nsIFQOBgwLoEKsaQtO1E@eJR4zSD0ddGfvruo@mnFC31bfiUNIEWMQA0naQzKDmdU17ixOilm6jv4fnwPXHwP5uPLq/BJnGVpXpHE76v6kZdAoIwJGo9uRwNNJ7nVmkInhYr9DL1KCtwZxRabqrWAaZWyVnX2fJv4I7BvMb1ZxN/fRP/5HWiK1@7afSENe3UwJnlzDqtPjyNgxua81aPsdR@yZ7o6y9rbd6yL8iL48A5UCFJjWXD14PaaBibCFcV2A9kAvoXnYR02xfdsMlaRxBk4DS8D9Xnl5i7abrSibjiOWp7OGThwTYv3acHG8upuDYegY6HXl7WeR3OXb1NpGgfRJVP5BpYJg0vfv5mtJEvHcg/vlDOG9Zvph/Qp0YwtvorsVtM6YHl5Eduxlx1sfw7Gg7FEVuhK@EMtR2X@kZ6EM43bCUJ0kNmzFCTV@vPE575nm3SHGcHmzaebDMfnBiJ8WE334feR6PaWUuc6hSqmlzPpmEKze7wzr8cdrjA8KcdOd2PJ25juzjznsJoAS0TY1vdNIVOQYSTSbHouRPkyt8f6vSmZgG@8T9e7YVZpzBCotiRLulGHl9usX/gZrIzr9IsNp/f0C4Cn0aghDGXahj0tHVFYccp5OHC0Fv2FlHSC4lBRSK7RcHJlzDNl//LN1tm8sc7mVJ3NVJ12BKSrdDJlmqkqdS@ge@Z1QTdqj26QzkjC2pl@5olt@tfrh0PsVnxZ7iyXO4Favlwuk0BejpbLNY@E8nJrubzND/Fy@YAfPi@Xf6KHZGwtf10um2GBDEN65YcX@K5FON6by@Utz/@WGYWfo9jUm18u2z6lPD/KK1OESIF2k9aII7ZeXzdzNIxoYmOlMlDgmDjA8on3YQL@v0j/SZQwjh@EROxxPuDM6qEqpSYNZ8aQemjaMPEpZozksp7Na3s7bGRls6Cah7TGc8sweFLDF5fTwkgQQyqfaNAvIQi5WZ6NkXJmsjuio2snDuVOTtcvYQJZH2h5nH5EmY@TSjg0nC5v@isNQjrwbnii8E14TqFjqmOMcCbrz0ALRP1leU6j0NdpXHTvuz3Ee93pTIRtzmSRXmKwjkwnHY4P5zjQYn@QZhJOhcF/xy3Dm3IyKMG9E8VYKuiReUMyf9Ytg2BwB78/rzlOOaCWEkFIPCoeyyiz8wLLYiQlss7RVGXwEQqOzKERHjU/c9i9bf3I@UTcBDxX3DQNmbJSJUuutJikwnk4B7sIR1K7XbzW4DLs@5avpuQ19lo8AHBK2lpEvva/Q3/vi/5uFGpDhIkKZinWs6fSafV67iw7gXk3qXa6A5EYqG1/pnJka0hITqsDRzOfx2tTKj5MPkTJl0ot9Alt35DNrgluodvk2kJgQUsYXqY/fl6hj59XbibUtEbSvcwbpSWPmjQcabjFNGnafFyl4bO6GCm8vx12v7uDh@kOdjsP8LgBwwmSyygfXvTYyiUZ2yS25QtEaqmsRJDzcant5uQjiXs@urXHtvRhr7G/vbf7@iNNuk@ePPH1HD1O8MOoxV6rnccFMlts2/lgxrJlJUBsLBx2Yzs@PusPR/c@9bJTskSENSkDIdVi2E@PcV/LMkeeT4xdKid5HYpqWJ@TYRCmpBJUnRBTdkfTdUQEiUbeg1ADMeot0Tvg1ZrPUaAajV54HjUaPH2ZaOh6FkPXmBNx/@@L9woX8ZCjfksIs6tMhp1nqO099eFV9VAdvqqpnXdbP6mPe@/Uh@ruIdwgvH23@bq@pej/2u5BTWVSpngI94gFJdF1O2pGCOKrVorFx4ohb/UHY5E73pYv3w/Cc/Wq34xwTPU8Ds9fnMlLvheNNqRUjZajY@xhdji853lnBHsLjkdJy1goNy2@pIgrBoryntCa9hxr3vN@q9PuUN4M1r6DThSbe22q26EeJHlrrnYHoiQh9CSbDnFIWVhgXVHxkPLj7IbAhGJ/BRIjh8SqbOWVJpz9990UPKztvzlQ8Kixtbe7XT@s7@0eqJ29fXp9@7G@@5LoWT843K9vvkMSZ3yzt13fqW9V@YMgUMwruLr49SIezUUhj@xMleZnnHznB9T99i296w0NXl2FfF0zVssXPUifTtjt/B61ltczFzHUF1wR5aMC5S1V91@@pzlfRb/hhNMcBbP9QfZdzOFQl4rqOddGg2WDxtu6Hq407eVKPp9HnI8VIiJF6@wCw@PnQBngbMTT6kQquwUbFex9i6cMHssGNFV0j2ADlDFYqSiOZLa8HDxnkBtUW7Pbh8NVqU2MCPULir4wpibrGaaYtpUBUFyiqPewH1Ratx@I7@nDiq52NJQM6pH9IBnUY/kAVbQO2xG1qnNcjPYuIJ7Vmnz49Xyww8fC6on9sBnyKvapxkn6jbs0VDYSJPyGdDlenezycExdcQODIjHnRyy3blcGRiRRREkmylEi27ZRziwJmzaOGrTZm0TnRipxA@yEwvYoVl7Fz6tDGAdFvY5ECjzthj0xgUpMd5j31FP4dKro2@AdG2GPr6UM@syAiO6ZxsOW29ZaYXTXclRyc6rGUNtIcpRbY4J2GwKbUwj8ETAEKJda6TR5puIbtADTb2tW9uI@cST2bf/m5id2bl00o1QBbbXl/dr5/XdfEzlIrZOMnSJjR130ezQktZKPMtv9IY1xFqsckwxSsHnWH4w60odeugV84sTTHOXGxEa1/VLZSNUGOkzW2Ov3nEpPiItvqPWEmPIutTLHy9m5FV9JsGrifJqExe4O6IQn/cvIOTsLcIh0FWH7hRRhPivH5ud4xJiI/plJZMffFGLcPq1sbG9@yv3tlwCBbkUsSJxpY3SI/4kxURcNDz7nY4PFIfQuPdJMgML44gSltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPOrSue9FYt2libjz9HVd2Jr/zx69fK1IqB8mkg5PHZ14i3QJ1ZKoMuMyx0iYgjuwkZEnWe@ZLwDCtvH6BazroBfgc6kGOYN0@Ef5PixDTupOLNkkWHYVZd7eF76sNtqhIQtjj@o3bH4Wfvc3Kww2/kBiUKIecnhHRgYFc8n3HLIXnqylw2/PBkfy@O7inc7GT6eG7oG3PhfZduOUe3gxLpiUH1t3B/m0OWJnc/hBYantwM2CZJKehWU63zBksLVpr2vk1/jLVdzz2CAzmXuygWKBObRc9PqI27ss9KeC7YBKF6OBwu7a/r7KyPqGyJPewZGhpMQjY99TbxNq202Nhl7dKk10sW@XJfElZtJl/8wbzTOLdICq0DhJoelhhkThJb3euRerpmYVVCLa@Z4FoKJfG7ouRQfGRBvyN1oCEbNJpTgMzM5u5KJNPJ3aNwDXdAtGNXRt@trCWuRuxjYdjF5BrExSe4mbJ7P77IPpx2dQjChb8LaHBLdKkab6hdcIBVTygjPl8ugfndIvpUhjZi4K9aGgHw69iWsP@8wzFjCRKuOjCjljXyrFGTfTjJaPmsEEipoEQlp46USyaKcGIeP7y3O1QP5n0vPQUREomot2@cLmCih9/01MYU8POkxWrkLtjbYmxOTJYHmN3VsNevznTfdhCr02Kh8mqSNrOrSr3j6lKZolUTYbmMxtjEgny2urqo9tgT7bCFM/9Wdgyh0zKz9H5gNb3Cch4HPP2PnFufTcw6QkDzCGdmNabATNRkFSdGXNKqu08Gbn4ES6yL0TIIAQAAghP1uqr6wncZkOXGcmFzlmm2uAMYdtQGTVT1P82vzoI5Fvru/f99clgQyaYDn6DVf6b/jCOklt5jt8Y5xPu26e/RcNhj7PJfaZzQPH4GtPcy3Z8204MXqVVSOTzNrclbX07ScxuA7PXwJXw9mIeMcOxu7c@ub2XK627Td2pv66pB@xps53ai8wOs74je@51evMQYBnM@xKYPvgO3/24TP8TDoEBSWTi23we08a/FTemCGnNRxwUSpuFatlamuz9dtwMe/A0EmTvxyob/EAFeRe2trfjz9pZL66nyhNy8aDnUakgm8tnuSh9w4YuIKVBSG/iuzNh4aaGsZTE9ZrTPuyjcLAVXcvuGVtOhoXS0@Laswy3rheMgvOjZ8fBg2Ylq2jyDXvn8cXwqvX5tH922VZdNfj15Lo5/v03pVYfw3@2WvlB/COX1ioF9jD7RMG19rMic65G8Ef29YwY1nkJ7qvUskrW4ev3lM8PvGgu44bEBJeqB@eGC3HFblQ5P1o7rvQqxfXzo97xOi75jR5WRg9LDz18@IFmUZIxcjJ/NDrGnOruuka9SwWnohxEVl8NUXw1hL68CYed/uvq7svUbhwUAGyBaVtv3lCXeOELsGbD3ZN8L7ry9DZZoMCxGShImQW@FVTCPXfeT8Z2TKtDmFGvBKTNxtf8d@xnFor5i8GozynGEyRYS33tfM0smGtMRd5RoCxHHeMvEvcLCE6Sx8PBkHwdixV1riTqWgl3J30HxBFKsjjMfspmcacQiOq7XEfHmTgfhc0zINEltforF1PPnyu8EavFed7FgylHOOQLE8VjPOIAhH4GfNqAKlhzj/naR4aaj/cSHuQL71GN@J4MG8hnWFNECsy/1Re@38TlnxMBhPALonPl9Ran1rxIkZS7g7y5ADdr6YU/jhlwrVI6ZQGNBWypr5IAZ0txphGq1WSi7wtXIKfQiv7pFuRK/DbVDJvfl@xMEj6n1m8xaMldykkb@OkmxTynWM4UM5kdUizcSg3sdNHy6E1Ew2qstqJul5AWWiwk5MAj3@/V9T@09cdHqPPYIi/puan0XCo9L@mCVJIrTxN8kqnsZsoufknyfVPZJFswVVdFsfKSp55u5kklSfKuz8sb50f9RifJvGG7UrjSJjxPJeSclJ9n9L6k3EuVsQxu048kXfP3iu55i2Uq74t0/fjN6A6K2HhW25pMcGm@1@n@mNGx1XUK2CxL1FRKinOoS2UGVUXfwdTihDQ47PPzsN2oJFAelozE4TGT3Xj@IpvXSsaP3iQacotxamDNGCMOlbjOh0y4a76wSPVw8j0HBMMEoykzcjdM4bEuPHbAItc9U63cgpwa4NS0ySFewb3Ir/hjBnsaOZNvcXbigmB@LY2X281pArHQvZedTaa0NMF1EfmoGzVnFknqHk9CnC0kdp1dYFtnJHew29gGv2flhCsojKSYortN0ZROMpQM@97UhUj8lvl74UHmZUg69qAbXasqlhkh38LKpC64j6J4FMPXFLvBiS8Ggy5OHVnhu@Ir1Nrl/8oqjlsSiM7Mns/UYdkj@QM86QvpVCiv9gD5CgYiSUJ8cXqKy2S4Adu/gmjFjktnlM9Ue2PZ0KAx82hFrplHCs43WAB3O6cuEtJzMnpA6XgQNqN8hnS0mLSfjDS13dERYnk/HfdG4NKMprRyJvMvF53m562XOM99Uio@Kjkku9THwcX8o8fJBSsikklYgVfC1dLjTMY5G27K2XAOAAP1GhP9e@LN6DLq9aJMlWYMzhiT0hpHw8uolc9k9iN7CAy4YGWcTOIedv9i2JTNHVK6QmJG3BKOAzkOIw7DL@ZnOS5u8llZkMGhVXLaTF192WmBgObGSbuP02E@sICbAKEHCp1HIyLKA1@lUeKzZ40L6y7n2IgiasDPiXM2YcnQ6486TeoZ3snKdAmUHIMklfVaE5hQfc1uiMvB@VkI4HpMQgGDgDlKmodDRh@afxcOSjfMnLGHpmcKJP36PFZouEfDDknfhMDcK1zMwZ06@PBV/UAd7O0cfqju1xQ9v93fe1/frm2rzY98xo2DcvYBrF7tvSbpYk/T5dR8jz5kqwdUMssJmeruR1X769v92sGB2ttX9TdvX9cJGoHfr@4e1msHgarvbr1@t82n7wRB7e4dqtf1N/VDyna4F3CtplgmKaf2dtSb2v7WK3qtbtZf1w8/co079cNdVIZT/ap6W90/rG@9e13dV2/f7b/dO6gpNCyzXT/Yel2tv6lt56l@qlPV3td2D9XBq@rr1xMN3fuwW9tXbCTgtHKzRlhWN2kJi5q4ndv1/drWIRqUPG0R8QjB14E6eFvbquOh9tcaNae6/zHQQA9q//KOMlGi2q6@qb6kxmW8W6hC/bL1br8G90mgxMG7zYPD@uG7w5p6ube3zbQ@qO2/r2/VDtZV5vXeARPs3UEtUIhPyVUTDKIWpdPz5ruDOtOtvntIc8a7t7B38KmTPxBhCMsqFd1mAsMMAq0lIu3tfwRU0IE7IFAfXtXo@z5oytSqggqwqNg6dLNRhUTEQ7eZarf28nX9ZW13q4bkPYD5UD@o@dRh9QNkqMMg4yOxDlX6jluNfiK85JGYNWM4N@DuVPUdVd1@XwfmOjdxwEFdcwuTbeuVpnke/n@dTZROH3sG4bm7sdKe/nQZwePl9I7M7D0a6zFpa2@7RjOydnaVTRLe0azzdMKVkptGM41NpNeUy5pWdHJx2uj02n3cMbXFZOPjPD4NEAzJR2CYT5k5scj0/goXWFxsNN5XG7TQPWg0/OAuJVNo3FZCb4PPy@XrNiL@A1be2Pgpl4Xuz1OE2vhBH3SyoR4OIJBTqP@DmL6F55GvCoVWpIvh8j4Am62jWI5NznCUQqKRLzsiok1SJe9M8HtHswMX9Az4fLOBfVJYRnKmfkx/el@TF5kcnA8knWW7q1DAIpbR6PwemWqkEnaJwH@0R4JOm6vMx1H0@dQrutVhzZ8/7fdbnu@bMpx3ROvAU8@/pfhJdDpRPDdZnpHlY2cdOiE2625WYez5syaZ0v2SH3LLPPxpjPjHN9iIzwfsmnJVvFmtNy29H6Q4LJICpV1b4HoFdzJ0vjfVv9Y/YDVXXHm8PvH9lf0uYwv2gvCNSxPeEZc75p9Xx5KBBhj74iCSdLSHjELBKWPsTWzmK8p4hkxXnRYsf2iuPot4XieSkCJ7EXbdOjEbDzvXLvYkh1/uV99svtvZIdEJbB8/XX2ytp6xbrf@GsjvR9TD7mvZ69iA5nHS0zjJGSVbpPjwSHG8hyfszwxcKCAjfMebTuOP8PNg7TbSlkwQZGhujPBOPZjoZSPQIavYAce9jOHXmSNTM4CXaqqP1pyH16zih6QrMQ9oY5bumHvtGn8A2w5/M8RtgzQDaRZjh77EubS6YLmX3TGmory4Ycc9yJLPGj4WN26WBrzVxfazuF3Lb5q3nV6MxZQR45W7nUsSEvcmsVDGrqInI/st@xnRG8DsPYy@/FXzGz1@1A7u2N1dGI@qowMi444tiX3qZDNaN/pIQz5GLA84VTM1PVfY5fc1Ujz29HaydQzijAZGBYFpYOObBrxu/YhMVskWsC@WffVFOBXOOwBnXXOsfifOndUcDWXd@A/R78YrhRJY1smJUO3K1pExWT5aPxaGnCky/Sl6MPx/Ik1mwH9OK06CnlDLcQJ4J0oyVKEVLV@ZKJ0rc9DgnG4k1HQ/fUzAfHM75sw2TJ/eXMv9GiKB7p2x@fCR3R62vRkEAJNjY8Mdv9Yk7SykpdOLrK@L45yk1zwfeErPFWaqmIKbWzsOWO0KzNkKXnzly16TU@FrKqpeyMLthEc9LZkmlvLqfpwVcL7x/1F4wBsgdsAzl56J1eokZxX1KDNyQLtaciaclvWYRGrptxtP7R4ox0VmSvbrky9DKAK9AXym28lBTfpKzHPTHhd5JlaH7AUPTsqxTMbko13WnbAhZjcCnPst3gxB3JPRFSaIrkBnV30JNOXdZ0MRVJJYHSZ@BiFu/TyRlqfVK4s970yCQy3273riHz@SXS2TIy8OPjSG7nX5vHoTjgnl7t2aLSxWeHDQD2C7iMpkW0KXR4yXZr8/JNUxRLsJx6Az9vPqg950iHrxxVD7L6T5rDPUOxJG6adqoDbJ6p2nGXFMz6jFnRFuK7TyzB/cpPMIFqLinuQ6t6Y8Yl7Doxtm07Fz/bCkvOdJynOiCbslZSI@V2vq61fJJQTVLkMjpmAntosLttnkenDuYIffVX/4GXM/VKBeK2pZz6QOSN4LlE6q99jHY3MkTR/0Y97RoK7ADoilREk20qyhKs3RTzQ7abumbOIdE75LuSXfX49lUmMtRRUljKtrJ@Zby1Fngkor2jWodRZaWlllVGYtuL7duBhjb6HpY2uV/dSzIqUsSkTlvlEd8SRy0z59xJPe5K/cjzF66AvOuLUKCoShs@JcdVrOMX6wKfjQiYYtd0@UNJlWOMD2Gy99@j3mRbN1qN3@NcNRHI1pBdAsdK4LDKPh/aV/1mts9bvhaaffCWmdBq/y1yLx8DjmR3TY6bB/FXP4IonJ6GRqjZNn8S8jbtjwbs8l1x3XXPEoGniumcJoOK6eiZsI3jmHEWASc5X5ezDpI82WebyaFMqk75@yPV7JX7@x7KPSrMJyog8AWsBtTFhQyB3SEV9Mci6frk9lOJmXwcHxROVU6N9gsZfC@BmRiI9hUhgbZKbMEtxGYGV2I8ZHreugxT4Ih3C0FG1HCLMTe/w5CBH3mqTIj7AUKKvS06JTVE5RruGHEA/jm8m98uSfjD0h8CfQLz2axS2zGIFFXNt4W4plvaK9jBIubB7YYRnNkpikWOe003OuH3JMi@tJqOnk8U3UYMsfUoq0m70prsSI9Gjhgyh7XoNETmPsY1JZVss@@@2AClIdecWbGTa6zX6WBz8OcWXnDIJpS0P2HKRvIlWTqIRAwRPmtS7K4lP59hGzsnLXXpsgYGWWyZkT4drLGs2Fb6B0ZH7FsVZ/SMI4O0E9beqxHI/6g@U7Uu9G2THTM9ssWjd9/1ZDYGG2Ck2WD1pM2soYj@P1zCQ@E0yTphhbmhEPYfnKz5bNJ4l4XWlgvFUa41vocBPNErspO6nY/m7J2MekeAmLXjPR2CHFuMNJ6br9ftSghjduliAapiyvGiwxGhAZjbE8OqAmyGSpdHcKMfdp3Cfo0SLKod4W0c7tnxuJOmkkZ1yemqSUk0vQE47bcWmT5NKgDeMLuIkTDdcKKatwXgdjPsor5U7gZBgJAhBacZRL9qFkBzfprAk@4ugAba8Ba6ESJBE9bbgWDtbpvyUYe@XXmzva4qExzpWO1wXStYVEqwrONQ@SuW9Or0eNa4YyRQoa4jNIYVs0JZvO7t6qP9sWykcQpDQna0vfYoDG@OohYUN/3KTGNXTgpCpdMjWi0gOhwaKBxgKtUk67kSxXof11hsLxsG7Qw4gWEPLZw89DXQLuvNeKltooct0aI4uvyS2jzVe5DSmSMJS8g/x6KIqqywtXAhAJxlS@UiIIcGvK2ONQgF3vuJyXQlT3ERWslDAs6SN7RU3sPGekg6g6w@NVJ0dxVo5nLozcTCCkWMzOkyBCOsvsLAkUmuhm4uLkeDK7PUkOUogN7wvFqSt0r6RpaHtOCMiBrot@IlGOSiooag7mxMerfirR8jenPis6qcXJVKKPxfAoV5pMfVpMpaaqXVlJF02VJHr4bq2pRCKF7yJspcKf@8dXU1yX59Ym1FlkpLQMbZ@NQOS0yqR1W/7XWD3nS9lGxzDw3JvhZvnVkBArKafs8x2wq2U@MoDv9j/dWmOZajDRsQLYL5257OLJgpA11iymejQLK13jac86KDBr2n5bvT/c2Um5fT0ZG0Oj82i4WiwWwcQnrvN7Y1uNraROv5DOXWhfdLuFwdVfhu9PCiz7o4hDApTNCjqiLqFBEef7w1OJDAEcKCty5/RFVqz1L9ptNwQDTijRedRtklN7Q1A8AXWs0cv7Q94AYpB6gv0FDUT7flF29F2FomhqKOYYikrDJPgya07PiDz40IZ9tj2pYmAQzMaaieYtv7LxBTMIIptwZ7H7Yv9LYp6cfRV1u/1AfUAAZHgKWPg2WWBnxy1QlCw4YeTbvRcx@6MNVHTZ6Tr3ipHF5XWAMxOTiTNh/MLDN/5@dFq7HnjZo5@zNK1Qkx@imQ/hnzpQ2dOsr53F3wGs8CGhfafc5@HAazKdJjPTVK9HcPJEGD0qBTPXPqksPu@JaZrdnhtEnY1unp01UNN91gWML3vuXm7JDdktcbOfrktt0LAoMDRO8LlytxK4avbPE4uXo3b7blKRwwBIx36XRJRIKH9OIPIZAI9APfyInvCi/VOOhvXOhEMRUXAQrGNa7qBAAwUymfvNym9XXrVaVUuDhw9VtbpJD7mcqm5W1TY@bG6qbXrfxPsPlZXV1XWRudv@F/q4aT5@U5sEg3c4HzbPhtv0SmkV3BuDtTa6eKlQWQrWlxqV5xvrceGouolr/fT0n//2X//z3/9boapf/gdeNvnl6GebKZ/PF5aaX5Z@@LaO96Pt4@Wlk6OlwfHy6Tq47O/sNbxfH@XCxHw0PzzJLMos4HxlO1KzzmbvM7qoMjH9zsPhZ5IuZbXYjAuL@msskaNYxi42I@d7hHuUJ7SEN0EHJpfyhMQiAR1jO556pxnBAI/mG6Ik4QI7UCkvZytm4x7uYGwGe6qyqD3xsM56GeFOS@JJAXdxacbKdXpx1MMO@CXrvNK8TCak386oofm38POb@HSzf60efPLUg6J6EKgH2Sz/lNae0Vd/qdDB7VzJRsuBbDaglORoAWaGKu6wosfrB461M0HuTGaJQ/YAknFTwZnlFlxgV398WUYCrsWnmQVE9lSyRcKHTCiy@GWp94265Qvl@JZNXbVhRaGhVzFcmXOiYvsXKlAYiyFAUvO5EKTcpypx0sc3kvFUMF90X2c4mhADBln3X@7wuMcHmouWetrmObWWQpgjNp@Xr5gb1@UyNKONFKk/QYAPVGQ5WeSbhMuLyxmx8nZayc2UW9hu@zTzia3DOBoZ23Qp9DflMIFYc7uEW@rpey3akFuOV1S2Y49XnKqyk7bfKuMUOb/ojjoDfV2Ba8eA@mJr@yYjCT3KgASO@OwvT48w3igwnqImukWCZY1Vq4@my0jo6avp1MF@Xk6OHCIUfvZobH@dGNt@gW@JGHYQHmCkrClfO@x0Y@11ZcjEPg2HJ4gOGLY5oNpIzs14Pw8RWicw7rct0nmGzCbnyXimpiwOhuHpeRioxd3@4TAc12naIs1n1Mz71EK4YAISGHy66lnNMwhLi3SXMEVsU9hyCMELumMdHk36NmvvnKBLzVDQblcwCFLsxJSMvqb6aoKOCVd/Rye4KE8Jb3saqUUsS15YGmlIWffaDA@zqaGTMTW4Y8cOnGxGULUj0/CCLnSBifacD35JknfhI0DXndW3APVVhLVnqB@z02nUC1OT06CbMRf9C@tK5kWMZw5FKdZIGQ3lSSmJeAesSI/8Oe0FQuYm484os@B5C59iHc5t0Z1H2Mm3tcUvhKpjA9BxADO@GaLe9ToiLCdmqCQGRl7V2fKfILS74SnhN74Kx2DFT4vej/cK/tHPn3rHD7xPva@ffvcZEy2SzSybU4v6MNtILD1WaGYsBKlXY5UWG1eDn3rpDJ96Su6wOCQgRAre0c@F468FQujTIkLdf1oUgqS6DJgU5tdXAPjCFJqLaSwKi5kF/4FvOt/7seQrmlv5F30oH3z5JSzMopK36WmdM2wTKL6n@9uFXDmJC09Xio9XSo9pJXQaXeeG0QXm21x8cRJdkyoRYzlLU8@n31PckCLEt@s4XKeP19ROCWsid09ifUlJi1A9zLmejGUrKpMXnqD8RGV2l4orLr7NE@LwEQv@QBHLmbzsC0pMBx3u8zB/xv1z1BPGkGuTt0OEI2FlIDYivIWaA2QTfOUmDvXNcFnme055tQXfrQyEurew6MwWvX4vp5U1P7@8DiUat2a6T4tPi5NjdGqIpkboklamlu@p0saPT/7jv@/9tjha3FgpfBjS72jxt8W1p4vySA/09si8XS5uLD5HtrVvi@MCrYHp8cl//E8qv/EXgoOU8XP6s7FqYK2NFzdyFS7ydXFjjR5KKytU7//613@lNizJig2xWJcagWLE1g1FtsIe8y6lqzpaKcvS5USs8MUswBALQ1qb0wsMo65XnhZ5m25RW1VcRtrzlbFH0VM8G2aN2FRIdjKMPQVpRlKgggpyAtKYULSVY7thzDbAvAma6pf7@bWYVgC/aHMOW6U13bgfw2RoSZZF1IGe1EjreXnYKP6YteYd5ayxKVk3KiSWdlrWPn20Tuzwth@NOs20lYQZrufN8Co6yYMP81HrgtZUvbjb/3VYuCSWPC@tPC20sblfYDvuwoAh5Qbj/O@kCOpgQLQwZKPTQA2pB/rncOEVcLQgUuh37JmUiSdJWvYgasoeVjomMWWRO36BHA@jOflElfb4LynwiJypA0E6sdI@9ajk3n5ZZR/ajJKP17w@sHnLxrHaBUZOrGEHLJvyGW4DdgdNe/LV4SlfQuJS8LouWfJhq9UIdZqXWciaUGlBZuEs6g4q2ba4d4fvVJyYaPqLmnkjlFwHOwi5HAs6wDqPRiEt0StZ/oL1eFID3KTos1brKi4ha1vn1av6VoWjrsyp@kqqvqIehZaQ1GN5xvHGptxsIlsq2KocRg0cqc2smGqLTdDmYZ5/gEEs3VJv41qCbg7fgCSqJc3RVmVutwW8FiYeuYrkzp5sLUrk6sxicvkxMDnkBjV0J9Sbl8pIQMALbhkWyvR@IDcgKibMaKeXEX9@E8nGv4cGw23YgytR122dOB@Vaal3idg3nRHfpVREAu1X1rXBzsjsYUFbF1s2BG0WGy9ZHyzVLvNiizOa7ihzGGjjEiqblX2qo6ay4WXbOnqtBIqgD9liaeXR49W1J0@fIcrZgm7tbDAolMcqYHAWEgzWqD1aZON7pZJdzsonhKCerhLQZ4HFARzMuq5837h9vvLvVUpFDayYZVhXHEZDiuvtSgaZQBxGecwItEbxhlnP@7F8hIYdf2r5X@l/4m/jH5AZzrijDYX0Tj@8TTxTZc7F4UCFBTM7xfEewYOKr1PcvFG/vQ9vExFsXYXtqaLX8AAxOhv2L07PXO7Ia9dWhzRgiODslxorqJfRKHEw5mAFXVRvONSd2xcVA@9ougUwysWUAJ1PgNMw034rQ21pitGxTJMQPGvixiqOEB3TUZedmTt7fVXb3Z5EbNENQ8dw865lKyl37MkMDmQQq9dp7iFRV3u74KukWiYFKa/KLOCKyFfi6/Ah7ko3EYjaoYqR1aw3jLx5ZCkxLyauTZOi1I/AawbMUvF2Upp7raYVIIgRhHo3yQqxwJ7nuCRLcHI7GeMUvJwtOzaibzpxzA7mdGVZX1uUciaOKrCQuQEg9m2KWWlIsYwe5ccaB16W3kYwR7kVja0BbYZsV6rRzJwcZoKtbmNxgI2o44YWaH99dytQ2zX6s/NhO4CivFn9Ce22IZ5vxrek8S2VVX3HdIHrLZZtbmEz9RuuKBGzFLXD2ARBCN@2REWMEq8BtfqOpr0M6qPU2D5OuALsGmol3OyO6kECRy@8B7KgF@/WFQdf1@FvZdm8mpY01qWKHhayxTV/YDs0WUhqtZCElHcAsTIJwjpqSbh9IWF4sUBnzTvUaxfD2PWd2TydYllZUJHavlMgsqd59kbKzGOLFc0WK2X04zy@YL6dyxsnUbuv76JZ5riFN@79Md7I3Z05cv9fMEftn8MdjzR3PCpD9gh3WLfhfKOTw7D3Z3DMyZjn4Earc9rB/lDbeUUjioEDgAUeMMQdUkosFdG2G8SJ8mYnPJycj2AktLKKiwF/qPGPdeMflyFz@XE7@n@18bl/cONXdeNXy5hrZvS8Vu0cd@v/mBYnKqGX/jCze6HuSjb/j7Z0Tbd0rYzZdEY3/19vae7/UEuf6JY@KcNjghw4iPv6@dwsmkj1YKteT8wt8hnttMtDHPvZXOlj7dWqZGnx0O5exGcVaOvqD@P/VOP/FNKInxCGDmcR1jbUruVleSqX5UWz5F0OhUtW0hJpr/GM7rRXT1jJekRPUCKkeWNrqBcqpJAHkpicNuUT/TGRvnbyuSvOItt1sEwcnDsLaFkRlvxkiIvmq4NkrqzZeWWbfSCrrcP91w//i5DhPPysb6ER8ujaq6jbNTOJuwQ7tF6ndGOc5gD2gV5zpFhFk5ORHenb3pZdFm6WauzYYmJenL1IkKM2nP/RWuoc@oYTlRtbRkSbvC5vVlUwzTXLC/lCbZdMs5usW/yHuPSZ5tJnZbWvFwY3kSrUG36aF5N12srq6rw5QErl8YMBWAwo/5xR9b8B)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/r7zsy)

Readding [this deleted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102833).

Code:

```
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
```

Not using `output` because it prints a space after the number.

The code must be before Whispers because of `Output` (Super Stack! commands are case insensitive).

Answer (score 2):

## 394. Python 3 ([IronPython](https://ironpython.net)), 16524 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse       22222222222222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11         xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 11 11 372364376371289369389284373370285329368367374377388375   366392393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:a=9;b=2;print(-a is-a and+391or f''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)# \␍exit(0);'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^;s0::PrpullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t."6F ._#^*2*giogrlopstdisp[]!!?48[]?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4otp:sya:nlet d=/;k:>;~ '-'35:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$:     >2y2* 001- #vk!>9*+'P:3+'D'34#v (\$>+1y'+*+01-2/+10k !8*+55*%3*'R+:8g,:1+8g,:2+8g:' -!#@_,@   9s)
endif #               A=AgRA; >82y/;AC;#^_"873",,,@_>2+^     $/       >0   ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7pdlWpWqW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixZ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7P2f3dNPLa1lBwFC77mA6MuyJVxFiTGXM0u3BVB8YrG9aE8NNM88wWMewnDPw1xjbntpTz@jVwZZlzDbO2IHdNXsAgU2cE8M23xou@OUYe2BYF6OLCes6o5Fu9zw2dk17Qr55xp7pYOlPuydM73gTV@9OTMcGrwJjL2xLH3V6OqPgY9fgkYoMQHVPKM6yT4mxJ47rGZCC0zU8z0HHMjjqruk83n360ZXwaoZ9pEOmxpYxu5K8qrJPTcPtXY2hsU@OHz686pplX5Mcmz28niU1x3anE@dgchV@nu0ODFtnmlyWtaueBUDmxLBKmVLmqlcR6tOYmN2ldMDjoelC7ep@LbKubkNtYV1uMWM0nsyZxOtft6ywbj2me2zqTXWLwtnTUcdwg4DeRHcnpj1gZ@ZkyCZD0wvjUWhvrHcNqWdY5sicGD1mmRDJ6ftQALTdYyfG/Mxxocp9mI5tzSGi0TX7JkYJ8gEA8UpMhgaHM9LnUMn2BBoH05kH2bCMAFpSiEH4B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjkrWd6escCoJ056xl9fWpN0qwDfoBkcj8bGrbfmAGcDCCOHZ6r11PKmrFo83qvxzLQjiEfJwYzAWuUrQrLZsGdOS5gDUIFOfKBUbvmZTRmUGdQRX2nwvKZDPjvhy6YW93yHD8zy1lDTxv6KtUZwn3mOgNXHwE2egbh9JODZ8zrOi7Y4MawvD/dBKarT9j2NovvP30QZ/WwWmS3I4RVVGPnUAWxwJOd6tYUWki0JhyoHzeMLWCVxTfiFRYHtGgZlsuxHHTbEtPygCQ1UwYD9H8tq8JdYFqJ5VToQXmW1YrxNKbVd/WBaRkc0gAhFbHxQxANnpkcy6olHnLgWH0erEsJFlm2xApFVsyzIjzLrKxBigg@x9RyHu4C3ACtDNlR4c7mOKBF24e2iu1tj/X1kWnNfegEvsvyKisCRMizCpC1EkCAdzaLdxZuytbyFYU9GQLGh/opgJcs8wQpkhESJaxGBV7K1pZCVBHJLk/eG2LygD5AXL7EipB8ATCRgywAdrUSJJ/P8IJ4Q8Oy/GhDD6NRbosZuCHnRcBDCWogA7jMIDKLcIMdaJ4GxE0DSqYBcdKAoGgamLOYBIQrgF8BqrPg42uoeyeQEE9H6xHygaoDGBWxjYRMRSQBBKgtloU6K7AcNIYsNoZ8lkH@IS/FAgNaVlJZKcdKRQb4LGcY1I0K@cKWogINVSE/KgKD@lehAaiQJxWwrQJQNZtnQgTZahb9IW4W4gJq1BzEyYEZKk4t4A3xoGWokKQKaWpaedEQIW9aHsqbz1IL1QpQu0XwA7xpkFcNmpMGudVK4I9xS4DDEjZgaLYcETriAWoFmzy0Q0BGHvJDcCEsmLViluNPt8ZDvYMUm8fs9DFqAbtCAdEIUTNYPHjnEJuQlQyAwV4A2degBWSpx8A7FyZvqQCkgeCNnklE2jKBfqkhhoppapCv9fFkgTa1QDkazyfD0E3jbg4QTxMIoDHQu/PQE3pfOvRcuBay6KoRvV0AyuTQ1QPq6kw9awEkNOQ0Sso4Na2FW4nceobe65ve8N0irzlKpGPoE9s8WaSSz6cjSNUjHgX0WHIqZqNhJ6YEQ9ZgiKZFWbQihhk7YQUtZVlVKXsdoz@1B4ZULkXyRz6TqTuBwWWRZpk7u@ZgAOPyAo6apmLSYLlwzlMOrWx2IoSOiF1M0zVhCL/LukNgKkLPModfLi9gZDWEMdc7OLJLwInBSFDGsatvzljnbpdGjkUGs4Sn7tAcB4ErawNHKpcSmZUKkbZBmHtbyoSkGa@W/Nox7UScxZPCpQDjDecuo6M1DGqf4kiFYy82XRhbHeIcFuQzYQejYxKQtjzQw8hrARmFSunqOArjmGTQmBrAMScyg0SAFTScU2RdaWBcSsajwbPjIqcKnE7PcF2GYYG99dI0zHrTjme8mSIvtchXH8ZtA4b3vm5aYQZoHNEnxATAO@5BevPlbPddZ0SDzQiHUctxxmtYFhi0zxDQI@fMWGR9Mabr47EFnBO4G5xxg8yc6cRzE4MeTZVnCCJhPKhwAEhJAcdhukaXcO8XHWJngTdZzmKFafW7WYRyP8JSZaGzALvhYRx7alkV4HWMLsvWlZ5xqqALZ7uW2S3MQ8CIATvlg@jowC9jzikXIaS7mkws3nFQs54zWi4aH18PwqIPTWSOrDN9DrXXh6HVmOkj4OoZss7Qc9kIWgyvQawJkFuwWAes59jxSQjlzAVGFgodloSYZcTJxBwZIAE5EAVrPEeZxtGdctaZQ1MmbOVkEnl4Tq4gShauIoo75CIOvLMAy9ebdhFrmLZpUwsCNslDPt8FUsndhInLmk0dbhd4urEv5clowIDPMWsRIcHjvd3nvrsEEflUw/ZAtPBkZqIMBi1/4PShsZ2ZUHYgWBB1AbtLSEAUhE4zuSsLhHJsQKMTi5msOx4zcIdBCZrnw0wJ2FDntcnegqc1BDGiO3XdOZuNoSbMEYSadJ1@H1rvW2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1Qyth6h5xCB6Y6Xi7mwbRoQxkbBZO/ZL7KBAWgHprWPEio2@UUBxmMqAqFCtzlDa@uAKSxCdzwntAixRYy@48jo3nMMjxqL456EXR8T84wBdQ3oZ/0FMRohgw6t1CbBogeUx@9eCB8TFFYWBpPyW8FHhg1dpwutEjo9VB/W6S7rg6AdYWFR1tC7XWM88duJQ@TMtCM8/@FD5PnJVfKByd5Q2LzHtq@0GggatpwIL4syEGZ97IsiOtJaX5qXiPEIxU5OWaz5teQhxOmV1MVXGGYpB6/ENXkYU5dAAYiIxHSCpASpo9kdIi2cILUhfht6mzu9XnxwiybvjpjUD9PG3KhAdgRZCZ0wH@thSHBb1wHJYwth1ZccMOiSwy2gdW@0ArITZtLqRV1lRZeBKN4GdOTYzgqogMwQLgZZ9qG6oMb4HKmGboWNkbqLt1RHSLAXE0w4kMEYOh47LvQMTnTmNJtAVRZpXb4QngjHiqTM7i8PrTBkxHHAn@AoCBHGlg5tAbsY9lSQrHSgFEDEuJAMNM/hKUYyTL2eYPn5OyPSzxsTjKW2baBwprtzDgSKB8MzJDRnpusCGTzFQYKPQcFgIlM7hTFB7/WQsiI6qN9fTVzGFr037Zizq5J4Fx3l155wqrusj0K4C0wHdKJEvO/Fk1Vyp5gRL1FxxhOFovKnCAEpkAxVnuiDXA@DxEMgNM/ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpNgwIicR2Mfg6hwNXcoPmCjGZ1AvyZblQ1g@JYkeEroRjlBD0VGD90FPgM6IUiZ5XKvo7MLoB4uk2Z7XBQJRBJVzoVpGXYvTMtHBOYlWl6ZJ@G5XTJIkVENS4DBqeQ0SCwh8AMxQRFFcFAUf2xFB@L2uB/xNdxxatNcHEtwViTJzkPmFwaABGXGBObD7JqTts@u3L0bMC4btRo0NuCmgGz2klGJNpi0lIFSQ2CZuBE/EXniPJ9g30gkobwY@JLnBtgmaKm1OjufDF3ocWS/FCAQoFWwsSUHiPXr@al5Mu1drWgbHTGQiL0OmCazOxGrAgz@vDfUbsJqfAmrIPXGEavYeDE@gb7WeMkVK1T0g7mGh@xvzc9KpIYTmAO/ra5EEY/quy0a9N68a/ksATdBZ@fUqAPZP/Ens0JClPZ5gqDTXuupHAh2Bw6HPds9flTz@yL3VDqmXVlysJyubpHzJgYXg7iPD@4f7R79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4Qftm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz8OhrV1ECnBCig1IAM95XWBoeBpguoaN7wyuDMBukUpBkGCUIy6QDFsAMDZh19NeD/Dybvn2LlXc1U2PfHXNmTXUOIHBUDuwgnoyeVxiwwKvT5yMixQUu1LRxsWFhioYM8vMRcs1XM0OsdKTJfHT4cP@oRmD9eTWJgijeBHgp3e3J0OatKYjgq8IA@QNTl6XkRcaRn6a8rkRwt7uE4EXdsjXwAQDKOrLDJGsUFM0bQt73rpaNXKVu2ALIThCu8pVRfqj7ZTMayQcOcV0UeVeNouSxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs1eFCgtDMA4EPCNLnideBK6yAsu0mer/ew/f3wt4x4xkSAKSEHOPIvJlJZnCSi9SCaLe8oeSGiOZcifEsUTmZhUlHiwNiB3PRI@I@H3Z@YkkUnyt5qEsJD67u6B9iAI7E9Z00wGCQ0oi@PI5PZxja/rQRuxHcsZOGwL4nDuMEgQ2Ka1xdwdOPa1GtLREYsaw2VCoL84caOPYawx35LgSLGi4ipfcNRt7wyotFrIIpIIQwRKofDya/1UB3Qtyv384PN9GETUfCYTmjN0AQoicQhdaOpGXMmBSZCQ7OdnZQHDJcNrvT3wkCJrdlhon9CFEXcX3isdiWLKysrwK7P0sXMN46@d@ZWmBS68aYEhgrKDp88eHzzdf7L7WXOi5fNL9lymXADEQXod4IXkIccb9tYt3jWxWAguBn3Dxe4FVGAKAkqwYjT1XCDcMgaReQbWtBq@2Jr42BnacS95tTBn6Cu9tru8CT3BzseD@hFB0O5ZKIy4fMUax3NsP8PJZOxVFAV6@XDakUFoVV53HUsfKBQPBgbLUlQUXQ4OcV7DWxUDMuPNDR6DT24B6zCnGUTdGjkgvNC6N5IGluDgadbKMgdDkIVxcdxwk3LYgqk0Sg8kBJCVlbBsRIDJBrj130E9ibxpf1XVSrxdqxktp4hBsKXuD2E3@gaITgkYrQAVyStW1rzbvMvmQKUR0lUgMSZv0SSHx3AssBgwkjRrinJ@gByiFjhfirSCcPRmirO5QKWUfCZXVAt5BcQyENOAZ5Vwzk0a6ZPuUJo4EsCTnD7NG0RaYd/r6nZf3vINQWaB77sDRc02XjabdgsY9OZdyhuuPTfmrYbaSlbZ9ShbfvhkFVrvUvGw7QYO0HbJCE2T3mwNPevp18lZT6fe1WPKZDT2xxxpzJ7sAiP11gF63TOifQ8jKFFPZWsprIKB3ykrJoQsjCrgAzGlQIeCkRaanoL5koDpRfYQWg7QrUgEtpjN4OXgezwidASFbmz3phP3aI0E@RqcLfXGgESabO4ilfZwfnACo2PY8pFKQ@UikWZnRhzn0XWPz1ZCJH@dP4gPsloIgWblwxlpO9zZAI2AYpF4DpQD2hVOmw4Xs4wo9ENLgwQpTzj5AByETasHA6AzEJkXZJcXhKdELstFOrGdMxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17vNXrRsEDyr8TAAjQoXoeu0MN4xunyWlUemUoAQqLORMXJwKgG4KyIFBhVB54vqKAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfYvT2gYl2DzxdJIxSioEnts/jEVXalzxVdegut@QbeCgsfqWK/0o8DBCxvcaBZEn8GlLgTZ0SBPqX5FvS8H7C7Aq4YQomhhYl6zRkb9lWZj0uEiWSVtiLE43wR6Dy@sbERr8Tr8TSYdsC0jaYdNKXAtEMmiUwYTkYTxUiTCX0bFAPdWvHLRgB5lmxhG5gh5/DWHCf0RqWSbaX1huq/NXwnoSoA8xBawhfAiSdrNTQmk2L9DNdsgH@PlH0P287zrmuOfRR8DAwBt/s4yBISQLxHbt41qiib3oyRUc0FodFAFjPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpjJ6t6DeRDIF6TxEgeuM50DIxbI1eRgLYlG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkJ5M3iklUzrHdSJuQJtKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQT76JkgZlpWIy@clSL@TbCVTcYibjKeBLNficcALLTh6VGicEeCN6KE5A1RCx4QhLrqmQASSFqewu35ujIdzNxognHUDLhtn0Bf7VXBbD1LxKJV8y@NHGbolST/ge3k4YG5x8g75pfGcU3eB57SpLO2OCsbdU6k/cia68okMQpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkJB8OiYr9xPSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQTB1cj4dTIJbBFrU0tCpzLBjdocPim/cAOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKnIBLpI27FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGgHFe3LE@rBuvQBzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrQcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiHBk9wQL60QfyKPO6cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNIgJdbC2hr5HorjjXvyZAZRhQQOuFFPLt0B03nGepqmFbr5fiXww1YByB5CJaFUaoOIG3hJKngm/Ure59NCgYz@9PDBPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U@Epfbjoy7EGa7UN7Mm1nZAIagvhvT6wjx5lwKR8s62ZmuNBsjqaWTnM@V6dlbozXdTqORVNBN0VdhJ@6nm7pfBIq8N395Anw@i@On9fkSiSQop@Obkwb5yFXJ8vxeRBdc6T11mB5yOMNU9zMizhuBTs/kcz4HgX0mPr7PqGOAvciugddCtdQfPcSuo9wzyfwyv4sAllDRz9gmQLiPlDc9OY7nquZS3RfK4OF4VQKxxnHRW7PVY3cTyf9/pJzlpxPJCRN1sI5R858P@iSjBjNUp4Hws2hS2GigAoUJtwjujZckcLx3S1yuLL4JNyEMDSsYGnxCDgWXD6DQd9CvgqEFmTR@T5OAzjsMa6SEOnGtTfWBSbUuzafAZ1tLPHQQmyDOhAMbgqyNMKmwvy57yp1Idvx1yw9TlYdkPlpWmW7zle5UaZyuTin8Fn5zTaA2K5Xgw1364JhSvF4GIygUt4gBhWTFvavFTXcpuHRZLtAUaqCp4A4MdMyUnNW3G9dxBWP0NBnYrM5u5PRPgO5BHdMbt5VBkaV9jitwVc18In7PGxnziTg@DAUn7juDoHOsNRsGZVQP1O771g9ia@SQYNhXL7CCvI3KYQ7Of0Nu4bpBps4aRctj4r0NbL/8xrcK1Vavx4gsmM0BATd55xdnKRPL1gDhrxT2Rtb5qTFLuWJ0x76O6Xsq3tLOQ/quvrcE/w9LjW2e/TRJ41Mi0MQRjqufJV4Lc6CLcrAOAOjhHvJwYQ7dSbmhDgB2olgYnlVGTI1o0USyD7A4AlUWZiQXyLM@oVxsShL3wBJNWFgzr35KM2M5KXct/TJxLB5m@PLj@vRzdeJ/GRqlPyOv@hQYRlamQHO1EQ/yGKVPT9@sH90JEPL9RLxfVzBqUB31LtDYFDWFTrAZLTwFXanF2d3ME4SxXYBuhpIH20/PjTqKjR6kD8gdaQdA8NNgGMSF1@64EzrXRSRc2g@gnC/VXdCOAqBJYwklImAVVbm/4XNRS0/nxVo8SnCJKA7cbcCuDWT8tQ238geDDTEt0KQOBdWYbyobSaIim2qSX9D3QiXjkHCIqYRStBoMOktUDkILLJWq8r3AEBYFMDcAWJXFKkqaCd7TQ2qvgbOwNIQBD967R172chI5VZqcxUo2lzmb0Ln5Y/ARQjLoD1jZbKbCerv1zoyzwNfC@SU@wWJ01dOYFTYJjeIfM6Zggcbpojo0P6q5X1Sy7uwoJMhKaGpGCxIQBJi/hEBv82SP1F@kHkwGjkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiGYVMYr4zKQPoEwPXagNI/94wFR7oB6q7@RBPtsUxADMWt5pRZ9OAuvnF7hTqVTMRqPc4emfeLQek9oamdkNY8cYRh7dGJdj4mbUOmxFDTMAw@rrcudN@r06bEiAC17@Avq5EAT6j4vDEykrhzRi@bWV6S8vIlkKVl/eyqNtGBm0ptbQkrlEgXudzrmuqCABNwXFrxXBAMihe1Zk3OyGpw3wKkYGI@AcHHpZVH0q/uP2BLe/X20/vs/f6MH@L9eO0MYKHDmMTS0YejGmpL6ayvLj4oWeqyuWD5BPrVMnRBDpttAdnUXiqRboWE1aFqElyQY/ke4pODXOLRNfADXeEMz4znnK4LBe3UiqxbVbCCZ3XVhr@zH4knR8g8Idj1CAmeCTIMiEenilWDM@BJMRMRGMnZ7poJNU4waM6/34XQy5U9gXG@tRHOM90190w@Zyesd1VD4zvUbqtzVT6Y9RxqfDEI@tbAi7KL0tAYsATvgLwe30bi6@LyAfCd48F4XbDG0KWf0uq1VePbUG0sdksJ73EYdYXRDCq7Fn@uCmP4BvtCwHmumRY8PbIk@dGgo/m4IBfeaShGkmVfQbOmdOfIgwy/fysKdBUBxat1UKpNds7Q8Hq@Pj5IkxS@XV8eeyV2Oj1VzBArfzyrxWTQqsL/D9ZZaheHKHOmWpPUixrXEfNXGhGtBwzVNioOHL@gExo2NHAek7tTS3YXphia@yEewjLBuRtofNp6ZXQfYgTFTi7KqBUNHZMAgkhlsjVskhNuJ6RHZ/mCuQmNwnEQKTatJgNOd4JbRNW3qAwga36qJG2IjjUR21mGq65zhvZZ9GIJoyp@rR7S3K3P1AcRJsrqWDuP42uFgaXIQJx9vaahnpmfQYzViT1ZmdNK1Vrovd4Fg2i86jXdbs/ZMy/HYc3rehKCBC1jgz9UNOopLU7clmgyPmm@gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDY22tT90@0n3//aEULqRQqnoLhQrYH8dW/fdaun6iuCe3VRAdWHRxf2vEeMMQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2cNMiWLKCp/qW5MwLrmc6fPg/XMMHetQGwwd4zmx08DdYYRyCQwTl7PYP09quZtT630YUboGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR81qVMi2jfskYaibz4SSqb02NqbFS0DjsvDbwaP0NQsaHZyrjF2PTn6nHxQE8mhKGeutLhh@Uaxyn0XYjMdEts2vczsosE7UxcN9jFJ2fgeEZGq7HGNjT8VKtLkln9tHNKBuOgy7t9JZyhz5flg6VbuGUlvhzz6D7RomJS3i4QayWz2QyPgMTWXFZstwkSWXDuK9N/lxKmFwWKS/C4iqbGzGuToPQEt2CuJYEaesEewpcLiu2aRuTOT4/kJp2HMf6MjUFRBUPDDsgrUq01famGrvG7viHSNhi6sLDCY9Of92kBR9tfNkS8INC802VHl0S@qDalHDRc4QLUsvWm6dvIgtMt6WCh1txTohvvrXW85L@bIgql@Tijb2Oc6hOx7B0/poVcjfBK8vZG@EtEw1/sRYXd/mS7mIpPnaFKI3ngCyzB1LK0BgZZL2By9d7qCbDf60NNHPwXuc9M4yuMts3uusCjE2gCzY@l9aQI8zSxLFBvprgPj@UUyzcSeq7rqPAwarfSiQfjPSBwfW23EQpFxMWuJuGi3UL4@qpiwrfQdOFaAuFHOubBHSqE2PuBe@VAJ/Mu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50A/oLev28J6fYi1h87QHhpDvm88tK3rHNAeJ1zPzk1Zh1wPhriVbTxe2uIexaflWNaH4BNJIyeUjtNfmad9PPyKJ7e@FFx@0t5/3Tp5p0847UDD2l4zNKYwLnnOxBkbEtnWBbVwooc/19HQYJH6551BulHOB4wE758X/q2y5UB3JuMxvdpja@rRg6JKdGb5Nr6pz7em0KZIxx3Ib51RR/YdZX/fCi2BryYxHXPSHeKhcd6yjYHT6Q7N2zLtK6pQgikfbv0g2RUxYzLpATrLlgnodecytpda1P85vg7WVbo/e8SHtdBwA7@yaoaOjmVLY/2k6/HZUDSxCk4IR3ojP7xdoePvlTdTc7IAGtnLFE7v8mUJNKzLu797Yi1nRWckFmTY31WxtpUSk44MuWRkgOFR1yW7vM8t0sWyWf5Yl6FoKSlHkX0pXwbd/t4fmh00I/O24L7UvpY2La0c5OzhdOBdJ5h8ur4HLBo@1k9b0F7myJQ1jFm67b/WoVmzFDzkCO828FxT48Y1lfyNiyoUTrUk3THh1YYXVN107RyaZY49/mRSf@1SnL@XCWTxq@uFHDfz1cK0XzE9o8@XQNB0G4s4clzciQw8iNTFlXScQUdizhkvTrhsZwBEXbLYInAQdh3bsnKb0OrqD8dM6bOnxkDHvdaPzQlu1lzRKqjJrtpedCvsr091z/z6FEq2rrGhxga@DOlGj/ajbQW8J/rA7D5aqogwkz6C/Z2e/LXU/NHpel2cDU0PdzSFhhsmprDJ8UaMra4NcsOKkFfn7UNlFYsOxI9Brgy9am7dGc/xtNicTDdNq5sTmmX13@tEx3WbwG7MxNl0NJ56/mt1HmjPVHQWenRC7t6ZCcClN0Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTrsCF@YPiwriOG//ctJwB@7yUYcC0AROGzPmKhnMfhudnuCHHtVe0REr7A5c9caJDcnnB3kDdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBGwvDRw48oaA8xqd878tCkI5XY@Tx7bz@4mjyLeM7tLznztTtGmgM9Y1ExQI/VWMv2H2MJzoc1JdyFpXSuo4F3QsM1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtqmIs2AJb6@/@RFMtoaaLf2bVxooI9sYVq7YeBKIzNtYMTW09Hl0IEs8YDrSTqircK3xNlFZU5dItcPnFXyzrM5DCAfLDAB8Z@OHhhdXDa8Ne2nzhPHdmA0GgOhHB0Z/Mz/0kaP1REx2mM81Q746d2azHMCu2YQ4tyGPjY6UL/WwvQhYxEH/ECf6GuGIpobJPkvNN3aVkyrY7ivadIvYl4n0i5n6JExI9lifYPhfVCadLucJcb5uKU@srRi440dx@ZPorYZeKlPbqYqMBTQ48MXymXciL80L7BSPlsu6uEp3yVi9LhSinVldY2OY/HnDXuSbJPvCdBd0/CUx6jjgNwKOSYB9@XdSEOKN9KQhWgEnOyp7tEi/WpRYwFSnX2JLUBD3e06uBLmG27YnRNRTHALmQ739vONAx1A/Awolt6d@spCb8uWNeqM6LFWYIjU5pHRwVNBHdLmMdFn1yuTzwz5qgwiO7pCBQABucJOXWCJZyCNJG8ftpbkqGWsmmN6EKVeu1xOm3Uk2zS6b3WcNXMIX4u56SV/KLPylIxr5qoj3YhmkRWdTrqv7EnLW9eAobEMaTJ0QeZXJjdNbwdqVlash0xHBi4yL6/CrGVdHW9IhXVWr6eHxNU1JF/XH9CSUO8f5w@l3bWcJ4KH/@H9jxUYhNuFXKB6BEjX7Sv4kPmpa/uvD2mBzxxv0jdnh5BvPAWwjpxgsfIQBV68Z6Bpa10hoPbsqcVnHwaRfVejHoljEmliliSLyPXEkAz7VCJFcLPrJXL4oS9lF7X3Toye5OtBwJUG6XFw/isM5r9XLKBGaSNu9lQVjthZIedv/1yF3LOAMgC/5UyksUdvZew9O3h8eCyPPXXl@LQ7xNMR1/i4JcUKWikTmZJ6rbuR9U6@Ha1nehPl/nNV2nt8IGOANfjmKxoSvHBlbum1dt4z0OKq6GulIPQ1JqsZxEfHTx6nFkc0WWJv6DojIxn13nv@PI0nTT5@vtI7Gvsh9I6@M1sb/WBfVZMrmu8Lm1YH11HPFSmtg3RsgDQKjfER18tyK3PVdcZG73g@Nj6BwRMpuPeByRfWFvKpfmoOsBey8lpEUUdlZbmQS0Z2ZoOwbbjhe119nphjpJZdein8tXY7CnIOWcXNruYeblrxv8rFsIy/E@HLRVIz11trVI@wont/34ypqroOz8/1PtQry6@trOUAq9aHLef0A5aSDV94kUInaQKtSjJv3UdelEZAuhV84PS87wjGztptMDcBCJ0LKzv8mWHPdVuitayb2IsKxMZNbTcG@dz4gAWpcIfPKSorX7nGF26pZ4kuGZO3JHzsRqLs7d0/uC3CkY/Lm0N99PQFe6Z7qITk5oDRHBsfkOMFZ/Rawnkr1IC3djm15wIo7UZ4g/Hq/lxhz3W359jz2e2LcHQGFYd2Ui4cwkIbBTIsc2auGqu6fF7r2eptRrelzQ9xOPMlPjiqnMYH9P7b/0xVMxlSPYRvNcOtt9RM0MFZAk36HPXZRb2OD0LS0EW@RQaH5Epp9LExw@0ofDZ4lVC/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Ob/Eo3@OVuSO@aHzqyrJxRbwCYv8GP5eXQ@7FjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVGbqpIOUbClKOUGdfWzotLPrm9Sw@Hl3wXytb67ExcXPjodMxcyvLsNtHJZPsCSpLv@7vb6fQXdreMnD8Ix/cvjq9s6mxMqEn@tvVHkRpTlZ6ARE0hlM6EnHde3mBtAM8r2EPTK5fkd13Jvtku0EwC088r96LYI4fTMfrcwy0ET9JcZWcLwX8FGRm58xj9/Fo3IJNXyH74/641e7reFoWTgyimtFHx7tB6zp8rmiRFBe5@OzZkjMeHp0cPo@4ucZstk7olWbrZMiVPotUnx7nlpLdrr88XYGs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBnNh9/Pw6SUDxbTgZWYHPx7q9mDFdqrCeM6GThis9n81ntI1yZU0P@S62VX5ud4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe0m6jZv12e12rPDY@o7UHYIPYhLMlHKiveMmY5YZBDinK2o7qnCyYn6XsPh8PTXu20mu0Lg7tIk289lZ3g1323HLO2ONQq9A68qCtBq6fGvY64rTqsKJUzt7MhWWvsFTr6oV/vcR/rauS@@sYtSs0AzdE3ERNMP5RV3kYWD7RkreG//h5EPz2sHuWg/P3PXM6uj0wgU2lbg/o3kD@rgI0bw@GH/s4GTqufXvQoDlVKveND8zExgeHHM27zgfkodPv3x5o33NuD/Rkak1MlFlWB33qTC3UILDKb98drHSvb9ebTbkir/NEbere0E2u98d9kc7UAxnIDIlnGFF6bU6WHIM2E3VD5e6GLdtO8grcjx32NVTjvgIVbz@wjj5@uC7c8oLNFJf46UTwwrhuU@94nr21k781B2T5kE5nm6Mbwz7jwwYQpAPXsbltRUh@TB6obPQTC17aV5LF1Urww/yeHHwHI5GwoTKSyx8di2omQEXkiU1UxLtJWggg7MUF2/BP/oOHGOgS8HUdoL5O054aqKyAf4poUtuEZGo1NV9mO/iVrwpTM5QmfrywzNUiBok12Oa5f46/UlEv2UaNiRWR@ZoUQi3nXFM3AEYdw1AoJp2obHMCPpuBFgBGH51hF4wmL6UuqnIFm6xE9aFUfT0JkKfN82cHz/afH@8ev3jeyLQufT0KQSlsG1ILtLXcyfZEKLyPNxCKuN5@0t9hQXL0QRyc9PSCcjH8yNZy0WpLRVsUStzBOJvntq0opEpCkS4hf5LIUyNfHNrBicMOSkwV5GsRqXCtDqScAuqIgxYpTai0CsusSnisA4O/afv@V79JR7743cIKfrkQE/ZVrUNLHDhOz0/RM9jtV5Diw92Dxy@O9lmQwUWrOTN7k2GtnOea@Ll6G6invkl7a2ss7keJQ13VavGHcUBMXI6zCin/IC340NAhWIAdVBvix95iiU2CDxiMh5Wi/OdvKJdxGY@JJCFsPMhUHJKFNk8NZWNjgx1DI2EPjg4@2T9imP/9B@SMKEIQ7Bg1D/zZj3v8OzKBZrDgm43uiLhx0qwkRLWPBCo5FlpDEOfUd8frv9xI320h3RzhB2PCL14JAn1PCNrtGSn1vKLwMUk62PiXJn19nEFC1ISCb0/giiTq1nQ9dmp6JmoGwTz0UdXlcmPHTYyk3lVmu/hZSvz4pU4fNYKsT@0JVyfnK5WKQUuTQ5qTZpuUWf4JJDESML69AY29Y4CgxjzbhKFiUmGvoSXiql@Fa46RpHr8WpQAdIVMEjL3kYDXdGN6StNV3v/aP1EGVQbmCZi/45tnmftg@xXf1gfzr3LzSwUb2nVdmou8RDOE@m/9EvCMhPhH3Ee@xmlzbT0LxKHKz4CwMnME1XRKWMfgPAX@lIAeL@AkGp9ApUFzgxrztfTw9Ay3lUAFvBVFwSaFkwcyjXjGjG9YvqKIt5Av5FQFMimdBgDpyxkD1MTAASaTFegmwqk5rr0CgXR7e5uJOINo1ApVXrPKpv0yK74KM7oJYYWzIWauwSAORFnEAL@6Hw1Gn5SaxKhIveJqHAlXz4Fhifxx@EK77SNCZAlAFseRgZ9imOGHWyfAV/sKpTv4qdPIV5U2fUCSCmMSmZKi4Ou3eepMoPlAJ118N43rt8EN@3wIRE2tHv@cMelxxvYoX@9ZC7UMweeb/L4mIw3goLKZq6NptG7FTxHEcwRREVc138ZL1pw07ZbC2yaDZvrDFY3ZBvMvK4M1bZaXe/e6Ft/EVR28iCx277nt4FTpQygMS2iKllXUQnJRpFxuZZH8EvnJQHFQVdgFJAdkCkhG1zBfO2Nvd2//4OPDZ8@vaaqlkPGrwYDu17dTTUlON1qhIR4t1nKV3H@oPH9y/2FQEYtMFyLUGAi/XxL1ppIsVkAQ5OJE3dWircrh1dKtz/GnXOfG1fxmtZuyRpGu5UPNfIl06VSL9JDOpl5NXCutwlY@f1OWFvCUCOg9rljgWlYTyfPLRgvkFDsWv94SVnSElzF5CzsBmJre1qaCjf164bBg4YfGj/HzjV60L2ZX90VxM4uKEFGvycQ5WaiK9B0iHpHyBskAiRRkJQi6tvcdciZ9odBU4x9C5xoUo/rhIhkuZG7CeATUcfBNdaQiC3XMvibioe4NLbMjBHr5uEbiQHFqqIyY69RLJAX/oz484YT/lfVZZSbTFtZEEqkdwUqzm5QbB/CSAnRo5O6eTb0he@aM@UceaKvSAyMwHTlAfh9M@dSmwT6ejiBcn15HBi0bA@WWIDJgMh5mlfNSQCV83cazFGqPhvQaqOHYL7g86uUTs6Q8NGY9cwC0PZFMA0W7o6otFuo/xkKTvmM7LlKdLWrhxq74EaqLiKL9SynBni0yoDd02bR7xiwRP4snKy1IH93jZ5@expPiqrZEyrh97dS9q1q5w@wX1ZspiT7xe2eg8noVtSiXr1MJcLsKmGuHDL4wVy7LQ0@gL4bWkHN/PnEfgxHYiER/pI9ZYmpzzZoyI2uimbDTpHJQqnOtvTZLpUigghd5yIxi9snEx@@Ebs9ZQqnhR2XB1bN7@HprjllDleUWmCmRJNvELz/uAceFumaTAgjBEKVCYGvYhEDMgBzxTiLzBg5x0B/Cwov0k67wpg/h0eqagzihUrP6XRb5kucy5yiWyxW/QpepYplB67tODmUFwF6jcwFfD9j1lW4BzkD8lYXYgpBfp3gxSjfGM/LI19YF2YlFNG0HSrwYwFrowe4OXbwT@zb0FeAPKpUXxw/bpaQislDr18A1e7j6yz8WEYp4/ue9oJsqS0HjVS7RfYTRUL9qm6sVQzWfD6nDiFdIaiyKBl9HdSAse4u2qao3tno/ol8LEDKHA4B/OrodgEOduMG08Aq/1cT@Zz@LIbOR2FTVk7Z7mornM1V4qNU8y7M7m01J2mxkavc2dZCiJm9mTZDJla3cg1Nj2O8dDJSmKLIsyynK1vn5efzh1jPzZZ4VpJ6pFd7M5pfZQvbN7DKrlt6cjNVCQ34za4mlWvqkxZ49@@xd@11SnJ3O34jNhBbbO7wQ1RyK/LFKmZ3vFLKxkzKIn5AuYyfsLVwnfYZ/Mr/tRcw6mjt9EGHjIos1m4BxVSyKitKIt@BP4v4ruLjg36jLdXmn9e5dsqHrk9mcmaY59no9uJ0hcJBa8jkDefkuUHoeQWFNepMEhddo1r8@n5BnbLZrDAbTfb2u4cF5@V67OjenDydPPv80uF7g9fYoEu2t/6npVCohSY0V8xSVtp6P4Uer/@wnG5fp82ft7T/75kgxNvB1iK/vXD5B83M1f2dj4879@7lcWtM0bn72@bNf3N3dzT1I55818js5KbOx/ad/srGhaduastHyPLUVb5ycfCZqmZwo/9mP4u1nz77uefXs//mNd3UVH0V4nLIi0Am4skwFIz5LcKvIY33oFXsbg1auxub0a8cC9/MNptZ3iv/le4dvYpNYXVM@deE9ib2JFUoxbgQD2LKB7TRWj21jsMJlbK7UajUwFv/Lv4X49Y8BDvrMt@FRzwewCvNYXapRlItYvQAGVdMg3f/7G9@I5JCTiRqxccF1jzXgEnNFTdxpwbVF17aA2lSljKIE4ezJcGI4TC3dVe@ixQQLvGwDP0thTJoxtZRj7PAeY0eNVCrVktsSXPJLmiRSVFVrqupdIAfSna1aTdpiXF9sNpu/izrvkzSlNXBgxDTufvoPccVWOVZ/bnBHQqywce/Vg3odypStZ7fqKbr8jkR9qlgSHeeeyNLsVRxEkEbr1WPGlVzXxUxJE9Pp9L022WeIK2kWtiS8@DMWC12wy7KrbktRIIjvGvvy4WL7eP35//bn3//z79Hv@3T/B1Q3a/fMvrIFgU6hS9ThulepdOt1se6K502016EdZSqlSklpXzYTW0CBWkdMzXx0Ec9n48/D1JtJig0XJVv3k0d7PbZwrnOXetTN9@CByYH5pSDDEtbIHGLtWjgYWv2N@VLjtN6SkCGqSQ21kG9JPFY9uMqscQ@qSdSKZbFV1/LaIbvXnvGLDTc95sRAMiwEePTzW1@UrR76LGz1qFOsHkSrL8J82XBhfoVYo6G0DBoQAjd2b6OyUaoUKprSrq@/oGlGrRTUMIxnXuw0Fl4cs7EFQmNh07zqFlRFaGFBC2ZfJhxUVjjZra29GNVStqCKVd@ktZlYhUaiZSVt0BYzqhj2Npzfh2sDfvSHK7Tic4NcfGcKcv3aYBV1S8sq@TuFfQ3H11uu6EAhwDjBup1O5223A1yHrnf0rq5O9Kk@0@f6pDPtzDqT7rQLTFMYB5ob/N2sk3dKzsy3ylIsm1c3Y3dplUfFf7aoZQu5bLGQLapaqZwtlLOlslYCl2y2mNFK@awGjqVsoZgtgmMxWyplizjGZQuFbFnLlrNC7F1jgx1xctZiqeBqpm69Xshy2zeSwcFbkpxZTIj9A1x1VVPZFgx0GXgAd0dGEL7xp6oCiwHHdt56t9V4twU9vZ7aJirbqkt@LuElt@@1UtLlZQPM1ar/366Hxipd3ASFa12mUtsv68DGvKw3UgDypQ9SlhgBldv11jb5hIn5qfne2y1ghKTUdmO75uzRLVNPk@I5J15w7rUA8PZSZu/dS8lgugcA6pvQsZOp1KYkbeAg2/AHHQjcqqeCUmEeEsB2nJ//nDdIjEAOLrcv65eN7cvL7W34b9Pz0n@D6@X2tT@9FteaMAv/FtKoZkOpN5WmT3VaYJeVOrrIShMMdXhDuEZWK7UaaIBLbv23@ZfTi2foglluyZBrIbbFtmKoRTUb2xJir95/8b/g3Xz/xe8j48ngZ1SE2DnSB2ULxdYyl17hwewnNnvCLxvMeAdWdEGHJ3V0tPnDxpUtRXklswpfPEiopUJSxpG87fTbqJhFZq8g6BIHi6STiVqpILZT6lxjsW2xUCS6@QvXrng8/o9eaeVinM/4oGaRV57nPYnkcpFPCFzVMqqkXtT5xzP4d45@YdX1j35h3SXELsrMqAB@EowjRohBO4opiiTByFffHuHRE1xzkVC8Pa19Jr3YlXA@Rp/QilqXzzXUDvZr5XKdLxdtPqNes/VgC54q/Pc3oBis2YewzX6tOwJOutnP5rUmfmkhJnXe4O/xW/yx4y7@jt7gjx2/xd/RBH/sSQd/x2/wt9vB3/EIf/ff4O/JW/y9GOCv@ZVsVq2Km@eEmZRaVi83ZyJhqBrbqTe/MnHnFcuwG2av5X9ELJsrs2Ss@RVj1jXGk4peK1c7Nc33lHDPHDxAKE5ly6rjsn78p9/95jfjtVpcitNHm3LgKnUwWIeCYaBsOZeMMYRJn6KtQpV5Xrx6L/6VBs0I5MutBvq1wEOI1dimuqlmrEw3o3bUDhhMlnFZZpgZqj2VJKeMwTLzzJxlRo7aA5MBvwyYzEyfZQYsY2dsCAa@YJq0MxM09eE1gF8fALnwM3FDdkfNdBkkZKF0RR@HVdsYM3PRbgoNFmfiKwNEX1mVM3LBbOEntRriq1dNZaullUtMxqYptxuvmvGW2BTxMwtaOcc6c2Oj@UoETiEj8iaMLizmeSBPV2NKs6lwhAK6qDIuL9vt/acP2m0FB7PmE@dw8T88HEWtN/5Hh86TQ2fkwP/w8BA6oFFP3UsBmb93rwZk33/txOrVnWaFBo9gAIkp2zvNelZCcyEFY4KGbqkveS0gwru@0RTiZyDPnIEoVE2AQHRWPa1Wz8jwKbeCoY1mdAz/Z77BfxOEaihOncF1SmDJhsazT5uhiRuUT8/A6VMGYmD4B3kzav2v8Df/2/o/ecGSLNFoJRPnl9sJupL4SybPL88v/Wc9mUj4lsQ2/NAB7Bjl/LKORgp0DqZGItlKXl5yN3gmktscYB2S2a5T3EU4GFxiYZKULH8k/uu@IWn/asarwIZzUT@foX4UE6tMX2zzaTZnGSA3neALMrhorV/QXopklT4futlpqK0//RF9JWgnSYHyuWpV3WLcouW0ajUX2IqlarUUWDYTifL1q57ZUQsgDuVyyWS1CpadAGwGrBC3wd6lWI014dm6e5cnUtIuLgKY2VwhlcHtVdVqkFIekjU8vevT7fODQ/rADpCafAy/bMVJSSJDn@fCT0DGxYp4926iZ@Cu/97ObvLuXa2cubgIXcZjcFKXnNrtnum22@ievbgQ2yJtyynnwZ4pXVyomXJKjScdN/EUvx0KSSUkld3R6pRqGYi8liuCt5@B/PZ2IVevF3LgUijFk7jEz0k85Dcuxqti7JzKoJaKnAKKVXSObleCvuzhcHl@GaMKZbl8MgGENAmc5GUMfy7SXD5q5fNJwMylyEOq5TIPmmS5QqKUKvu/2kaS1YFV4j/k97Kp3FZx6x5wzvjzZqsupMnVc6OmXtbOjQpO8l9Wu/5X2FFJjXH3brYMKCplqk2h3X6we7zbbtdgLEN2Cx7oSNRdQN09brxSvUf1qpbyDCqQO0pxGBJYCbCsaFt5tYRYEcw@Kp0CHAhcWttgG4JGb3wIZY6qDXAEKQhS68HFeqzDBnixAQqPzGQWXcxi3J@e3W4YyOGX7xtaKS7Jl4GLEV6C3@2yvE3CqP3s8e7e/nFa25ZYTHu4u5fWnr@4H1PRml/YyTuL9qP93QeHLyDCs8f7u8/3Pzr4ZP/FM3D32NniCqi8/1y8o6YV9jP2qfDafasbhm5MDaN9Np2evWGvTbNtQu1ZUyiUM3CZZ7ShLGN9Ua4q3F3T01@/1t0xXez9D7/9/of/3fvf@e773/n2@9/5/k@/@P634f4x3N/l7@/@m3Ienz/94p/97vvf/h1w/A9w/xHcP/npF7/xDX6T/Y/h/k8Rtz/270g4fgsA61d@@sX3fvTTL371B3D/S//@wfX7136y@v7@t9bfGO97v3tzmO/@W7h/j8MKwn73t7kbvq@F/20e7ld/8P5f/Dv@/1P/h8bfef8v/hgfvuWf/uBP/9P7b/57TSv96b9@/63vvf/WN99/6zvvv/WPtfe/8a/VTPTxu@@//wd/9Ye/91d/@D/S/8f0/L0P@b//wT/9i//1L/73v/hD//4J3P8OTD/5i38PXeVv/@CH@P/eH/ztH/0Q///zv/rbP/j1v/2V/4kMv8kN/8@//Df8@de/9h//5re@81c/@cbf/PpP/uY3/@Cv/o9f/b9@4z/@9X//@3/9T76Jjr/5k7/6o1/5y29@@y@/9c//8ptfrHl@@8bnFx/g/sU/gMuH5/ND4HxIub6syxc/V37@PthYpALtBFr3L7//jV@CBv4vGHv/7R/jeU641/x/rKkU5sfc9v8Bg3a9zOiTARPcv/7@299FFP0PgCL4h/j6TmhZ8uGW7ywsgNbfWhHpl3/6xT//EdliRqVOq0Y4WJe0UmoLBJqtctkfsP0FJYjyS8vQQgB@St9BCrXk9x2kbe9/@I33P/rH73/4m@9/@Cs4Wku5cno3Lam3rMZBwPwHhMOAhQ8JhwE/g/TbKZqZk1KfgW3js3wpa9t29bPPPhPaFwoeHL53wT6DH/ssuBj3woPFvlfgh@540piBe@PVqxYu4UbcFJUDVzT@9r1whz2kJGl3UjuKqnEv40LZ5LFYFRyypWwzknWl39@qwI/Bo1LZOk9LO01g@ijqpWAERVJ9qBsKU/V0diurQ0Alx8Oxin0vk0sVt3QdROAUwk0Rz7MV8GD5LJulgglrNvMnrmcYaLZFxhnNZPPpbHgK@KB/kbESyzJm839VYCma4@YrLamFkQx@PD8JbhTykExqNlvMmM@I36IcchdaH6d0c2WGJZjNUjOQtsEAKaTA6z7w/bVaCiPWeBbBygtTLzHKSipVg3JjbB4n3S4hiNl9ggIxa6kj1t6qzXjEFMKrB@hICeh0JKqamCrVHkCCtdkDhrAQOIF99apWL9VmdQT3jmMnNUvdpzwhsFpqVn8H9hrBhHhC7ME7yEqplkrVS5ggFpJXT7rNKylPhaOyp1jKrwN44zGHnXuM3RHVksgXRzYQYTw0PlOL0BgQgoN/M7XlF4f@gZHuLUL4BiXlp8K4/w7xxDucTcYAAFeSZFlmcOO@gx12D7xnHFSKkoVXikNIUYugFhA6MJyISgkpqt8UWSD9WG3rS18IDAuzubkpxOpiVjyUCXWKwtyTCp35wG2QKMdUmFgoi@hs0AGYIC8Qv0rpb8ZxQTHOOGB2J8Xve/e22B0oJr0XbgKTUlkn58Q4lO1UStQAft1JCS9B/hGgnRKgC0Ge1WgBMyWk04zJtRj6scPDQz8T5PCyJqSgmWtZFe24jDadTmMQQ5bTcjrtv2V6k4PsG2Ty9d/yJiL3zDUnBtO0XBXEtCpDJxaVqVSQtdHx3bt3UCu0r6xyAFIu87eYabkSeYID19tkWfPgpJSWKwt8CoCphRxjCZoRhivJ8EhQAhpSUuDnEXg2gisR10qlOIUE/MuJrWDPYUFFCsDPXtExXpYvLlkhN1ErTgvy@eNYHUsWXFxYLeWTgefeIds7fPJk/@nxuNViAn7EdTox2mPX6Rqel0C/3acP@NEVrVxIxhoNxMpxRUOKJOxXMthQUwcPjg6eVxjHkl9nCSpHlRagfbyUVSE2Hn@6HfO3aIn4JU5HfI7PygIVCa0M1DIZqwuxroEiEO4sQNG8yqrCE29w35mxRCYtimm1gCJoEtdRIR@/6EwZ6onmSqWgE@KBFnl7mzAg1M8lWppBI1RvQajX/c2NTBXqz/ePIcLxIVO1jCzUP2MzGROULoW6VbMMezAZbuIuQbGZESNl2mxk0vjTsll4qrlCWs0XWxsb1rmEaTapls9xu@clWM8lLMZX4WLCVwX2VXCCC9LAPZzM30B7cFj1dzGiRsYE38ooqnnol0kBJ@o5OGEcvarQHZYXuoTYxuefT1i9DpK/dPBQiAF5GbJgI59k9uShTNXcm7oG@Q4Y65mfmPiJVblnemNLn0NfA2zELi8v@wDp4CHT6hpZeYwePi@75NIB8@VMF2J2pVJ7p@aKwtFupfIuq2kCOAhbCu4U3IAGQBsuthT@q3qQSDZbUoC0qaIIr2w2K1DzFSqGwGhTzbtMrSbxNpjNqbSnRsCv9uiz2mKV3A87u7MIm83wsOgDHmwwcVkm8CtyP99WEMgGSMNthPSN@KrfmzN372ZxeiWby4TzKFRidgl1s5nNZRHjeEyrFcsV/UUgURRbMcEyJqxXA3OsCQ8@VaipMZGhDalMtpQRYo1YQ/j/@@Wvc22P69mMuq2MwaiDMbet6GDsgDG/rXTAaIKxvK2YYJzWs2pmW5nWBSZsc2XODHVF1cSJMUPd8dxNrHuG1Zfx9FZNpAQ0cdv/OEI9iFjv1XpOd4obZ6o92bRtw0XNDjxCLidWHRvVjNZQ4RDpwmCJ5LkwqJ2R/gnBqA1k1Fzl2rol9OSO05vL3mRu4Tkoy3FrcWBs44HHAroBHA9O5@1ks7lKg7XksTPeEbR8MdVQMzBU4a2W0lp6w9gpFis9uWsZuruTr@RL6R4esfIX/3bymcpA/uzJ40eTyfjIoHNXO7kyREBdj6iVbadUyedbjYYophqUTAu/a8/pmrSxAcTA0HsSvHFp0JO0Ugsi90y3VovHd7KqJqmVbKZ0KSwQhzjHEtYFjJrCkqUR7@c@6ajYjg1UqpLW0@Y5YaHS7/cvt85TC4ugn0vcBvi5lPR05zy0VqVIuAqbpiVz4Qkueh/Qfe6velZELV8Sq43qwl4siNXWpXBvZPRMHY9bNTPn12MVgJpzqDFIqMmEy4rrOJNKx@g7rrEImFULQUCeoesBcuJlmFwzgymeX0@uEAk0O78OJZcXL8NYQbaEy0vAO0c2oN3X1F2nbckNtZxr7QPtguazHSjxxmCxly@F2NbRJ9l6Har6PFfUcvlcXssWCvmiBgNVOVcA8S6jZgqZvKYBlFy5VC5eQrtWlHcx@kYn2zsP2nuFvlKS0CtczW6jxZLvnprWeSkr8XwkktXLy9g7IXbn6BMNRta1VwJG6080qV7L5stgyqJJy0KGmaBpkpaVsqqkZvF/i0HD/4eH1@Cv4RNiZTXhGHVvPYXxFngEmz1GHT4Thx07@BW3AbtvdNeE2BvqtGd8z3U87@8R5r5un3CvByZXeB16PdLxU5beyJwM14R4MR6h2i7D/QeDsD/qQAaRHPIA9@HhWo6zKkCRvXi2ppRPwk9MADL4NyYg@NHBR4@OI@/j/d29R0KB3T98@uDKK@8HyrPH@w@PQ2uR@wZR8yGIX9x//Piq1X/lDl8c9aeOi7fw8PBFbvEInfBIspCDazlQ6ExA/AdaiSMFVgREvnwxMKgCHmS5C2L4Xd@YLyyMGTR@ys9bm154sIIfva8Ix8EhbJ0hpe0YrMu1s@G8AGlO9WUGtVgWhDGznTNWzLCeY1m6y5x@fwMchzoeKDWQE7YsbImY9JnjWr0zs2dsCE/w7GoZBIo@ZUJ4BEBG0y4p/gAuCPVww6hmM1xp61hTg03HbK0jvNAJja45GMIYfOYEAYSOrjO4v@wF8Y3oNbnZYcLTILdrPtb14AJIj6W8KO6J4iN9olddo/iy6mUqlWfuGIZj3RsY@zNosewF9CDdnadL6aw4kcXCQya3Yy@3tK0Brt9YzhgFGG/cAI5/J1dqtHaaf/1bP/67P/n1QQ2oTTOzl8nj7NP2zpPHOWcyrnhzvWJzplCpnlTq1XcsLsWz@QoQP2CQGfHAPp8sk8SklUv5UjmrldKlcimXVwv5fFrV0iCdFssgb2TUkloo5ctqupQrA5@SK4Nvvlz0uWwlYKuVrQqAtbvWtGdsk9AlD0G64muv7G1CT7KYHtqnTDQgjiigQDyh4/tbZg2GWKZmWLbIAKLOuiz28OFe5uFDUbyPFty7spcRxR5a8qVMpnhfFA3y2SshzyU6PE4J9Z@KE27JZO5DJUw5APx0iCgO0bJfwClFUTTRsrf78CGm00eLhvEh2An34RYrsBQhmI0WYP4JwJsQGgTb5enkKKP7aMEk0ech99kDP1H8KMgO@hzxYBzAo6Cku7uieMAtu7vos0fFzvOMfg0tu3SJogsW6ByiOADDwIVuKYodMGIXEcUumLpzHdxGYMKvS9gTXRTnHD2IIFGcUWi9eyKK7cAdk/nEz00esVshi8pLfY8sZfyJohZkGoNlQ0tWFHOhJQdle/ToE3046RkDfs1d/u5CSR89yurmbLr/sPPRR53BoOPOd/c/OkKvvb1HwK/Mp25n0PEjdtpwORBr75Gmn4zmVy8o9UG7XdGtlV5fa7dzun3Fqz1vG5hDiPUGcuZfA0xo1N4Dr71H7Xv6qrVzAthG6jCCdwev@yN439c73Cu4yIves05HrGLzV5RmQkCJAhfBsTueALW10yO96zpVtM9qLJNGpmbeKGRaVfJgI5AMMtVL9O8n8KnjPFTyfN6Y1TKt2qxW9Hez9RNic6blTTG9MdpRy/nKhr6jarnUrIIaRJx@HIiDusMS6t2ttyzxNLmjgZQgNnd2JLGhtnY0tVQpFF9uTUUxWcHnTrZYeZvIxDOM4SPZKLZ2ivlIjGIxpStapVgEXg1wMoEhv4OzPe1E4szQT5JJzC3NPUARqKxsTuU0q/3ELD2r8XyxebI6q6lVrlWdZa4B6@EnPKbdieNykAMAN9vJVHDDRUJUyyURMqAoiWQyJHoKmBa7Zz/9@vHJ8fFnxBTW/WmRZ66B1KvqWz96tCcfHAY2/PiG/BB5VceV95BqLflwpjVwOgYpRX4EwyxIfIEbntR0HUvep12HwPAGHoH@L9lXhC0fP1qC83zonPGUUdFFlbSp2l2D4bdJzB7Ta3Uw6T2WoFwxPXlGA3y7Xq@1ayPSBQFFDGJ9jdGHOxZgDjye91D9BkU/x9OLvke7lrmsdmqz2AzgtGtMUl@NnN4rLdWt9vCTJPdr9zFytQ3vTtWoGa7ruCLI22K1v2PXpran941nhouKZQ4ON4HdwCONiT4zkpusuY@h91CWuZTqLrMXOXs6HSV0qd5JLjvhlF/ogMhJfD0o9Dmdsm3XRPGy2q@xxEsI@gbs7iZL9OT7yZ1cFfB0n7WT4JR51X/VZxor5KokiyQQFnQlwg@WW2fJWv1r8OKwTyoVyI1f0ScAFRMDwGaPPCD02LysdmsWS0hsxpKEpFx1UGtg9At8bEui2JKkxkVLqEvSp0Id@mt1HtNr3rRDX7NimY6qZQrVGbipxVx1CNWrv5xV3dp46hpVC6z@TCE/UKxXAamAOwDz9iLx/pe@kdyW8jXuViVQF8gMtOV2bVa1UT8uNIxatgYeqUYukwYpHx7FNIz5WiGtFtLZdC4tFdEVBvx0Pg2OIAUB85GwEiJjYjozy8hqWjXUdCLzyuy9SqZPEsDWENJYMj1x9u3piIELVBW2TbLCG9CT0rYskM56DtO3JWqsQDKqWDDA@pCNzfQQQR0ZukUxkkmJZbcS1mYCw2weT8f7jValsj8bfx28EtKbnUKqmEm9TSariY1kzTPeCPWqUEfyQqUeb0DL9SdRmTcdNaCWwaQWtUqj0cEiFjPpbCYLpTPbF4NtsS620pmNggpVdMmIbDBON6LzisjxLNzGbeTOLQOqTi1rVUGmSb5sSZPKSn4rn@ETjTymMPbJG2KSJZpicHg@EY8XtXg8Ga/imsiG6M9pA00jehYH6hq/q@6IwIyJFbGsYYAFaaTz0Zkgd8COXQrIMbIcCL/nwuX55XZd@IrwHE@9bmsv8Vd8@WT3EH9fAacyWEsvn7w4fHH4UGAK7W8FFrS6UZWr7SpYJLl@T4hVGANK2vQ1eykbjH3ZnbOp7fpL/m7iwQuAK5DO@wZr0Y42w0TJjn2CWiN2WBzKoLujhqZlWw2tCGMfUNMgqKapVVwxiuHRDrkOlTE7h/xtp@p44PJrbD7XU1IwHXCXsUFqs8JPDmpzbYsBAyOx2OnJRr28lYo/q2RT8QfxbC52CpWyWU@p83hqK4VruUpKzZywjdJWKp/fupPdih@lKqVBuqKm8KnBsxJn0kbsXjuNq3tlLylQLbDYlSmJ3dru4Gi3yuolba5Ud/eqsZdtsVTM8kOMdS1FBz3ZZnBetI7ay17ijHtTwN3/8dh5nMXil/ATYvfoyKnGj5yyWHjoFJe//UWhbK7AkrFy0rcVyzEvEa7IfCV@LxbHhY@K572LUcMJTvR97ZUGbTZmO4EDiHU45QZjaj6PqwMx5dXY@1wrZZ8cHNoP3IeGEGtuXGw4uFbDFnsb39kff52xMSA1zpq12KyW87fXq/W6pG5rqGSvyCowbPTVgpS5qPOOUSePggY@73/pB7nZdgnsWkYFu6blU1q9rm5pULDx@y9@H9Ulne9/svuYxXGG/@/@5Eda8e/@5F/Rbr34Jc36a9liDEKiUS0UY@fn4/PzS7i4Xz7Wil3bpNAC/CiqXi5uyVAapaSDoa3EOB6BUSqqyZgnxfwtmYW8lEioipbcypYySfC58NWhJbRMCazBwhc5iYW8mIztH5l5Tb23vQMl28nmtOoG1KUaHh9m4W/b8MooRD55dcEYWLr13mBgamRSFFZ5J22/Y9I2e4drTu@kDfaqVsdNFioeOg7WZLbwECYuZMbrKWUrzkDAYvXGZfWylaJFHRJWX27ZzSt4aG7g4Zllpy0bfsaWRz/DICs5eGANbMbWa09MbCUVpdcTr0/NbRssX4emsqUsjkazrWCphv8kqZl8/0u/oWmFv/uTX7toX7Q/00BILZcLqhb72c@2p/bUM3r1nwGAG5TkBIIm8ZqozQYNoYDKuM5d048VGuQuyMZTG5lxHj4QV1FAZcDImAPb6JG4Kpwi80U12@Z6GnsJCraFOjTSxMyTXrRkVRACrpcz6@6gmyYYbAsVRTdaSeFc@Cp6wdjOgOGvCl9dgAKHEYzmTrftWVN3TIePEhRPbaXZXYgCKXwVdWBukO4Pf2CQgEIqW9ej8ix7hDVi1NjI8DzUqAljmvBViOJr07fmbKyjmhoMadowEskYhPJJHr0GpN2CtC0eoU2uCSo9D5BmPHc8kg0MvfBV4E0ICyawLMzchgBVICtfBQRAGRI@YLPFtlk2yc7NVKq6UNd5iQccUKGoHqjIEDAaQuuhSpYgchXDgRMIEvj9ZmwXfg0DxxhxDIBwGHybQg1EEYxONuQCSYfNB4MCWKQvLkFFY3fvLnJVq5m9JKMSIfwTc4xTbVQP9uq8ArBAjLvTq4hphopQq4Fr2OwA4ynKLrQ6iWtArUaiMhGtl4IA/w9utNgir1QVeVSxAH598V7RBZRBZEQ7r8Mu264xVSsmWZj5LuS9S5kiRQWhbNqc3ZG1zwLPS8jhz2LB19GAaB1Hpy/9dntVRwoDzn2Kn6ZCTXmcGPi6TbguPCR@B5MgdhgLimJaFLpvuiA10f6JQA1nIqsmMdpCbSnlg44gaDmGJwHySXxRLAzN4K2jOkk/nQ1Sg9V1oEK9sWOT/knSj4XHMKBFAI3yVffxbE/tM/yUoV83FDmaI4/U9mHLxxyTPk0HFQ1RXNyP0HFBug5wk2bGQGbdUY9pZZaghkYqBu0QXJIiUYY7wHwjjjuWMYIsPTcMOgLoVRRlAAzZtEN6Fp@Y0K6GD00YgWxPecARrJyZJ6ZyjDrFJaePJwW51poY8nDY/fjWB1@noeU4J8wyTww@K51Y0vnjMRA/gINOA2YXNyC2gptwtGwaZ0HUNA8FdxFeRW4spSNxNxLz5PV3Vt1ItLFGL2i8MaFWLONUtyP4petC8OVub@4FWsNI9xXY5ZDkGr6@oFocNYGEirAEX/9ZjVRvybjaMU6IMTHQG4ZGYewapwwlaAHHGCCa3UADD/ZiKO1XaQCgvgc9C9WJTtwK6o2CnLi9RBe6nk/gbXaHZTUBA3Klbr4CNoCBVV9bhg5@EBXL4U16UDEyTfEjXYHeOeqBH2os8Zsfxg9aN5pJ1euiebMNHxwOOpRWjfFuEVjyEQv2DmzPVPQN8CxADlfkZCMhpgBsSkyKHHQY/2p03toFoiUVdh1SmiEEH9UAhVgFHUkO6ouMfHNQAI/7usc/TOMrGz07O5NJA@7UNWXDw@/weY6tW8p4YAJH7CgTYzT2v3hudpVxAHdhkvjnN@XxcLwzQ762Vr47529B6Hs1f2dSIt734jg4nuJn5gYj0paHauo8alAPTfpEZTfhb5Ti7U9rpc@D9lfB9ieV4pcIhDEEM0vP0900AEt3uifp/lmv6nucUocE4FCLRuCIeqndwDLyApM57ochnAnS0dCrY53QmjFAEvl08SJpXsIg5Dyw@vaxOYNItnHGdl1XnyfIP4mhsQEn5sT2sDkM@@QDRlTaf86VJJuzxry1FH0WRodBLdwx4aIqPOH8ZqBcYzb6z7j/DPxn3H@2SDRItjFrcZYMnS6xONjqUYNqEBLBzIMwl1y79MKHIAM/zlQOAkPOl9wu4e7WKHaAb26DeqwFDQPaxBgQbiSUxstmo9myPeNsq5VSBtDYRUIE1DiAbrQIp2e90IzYt06tseMtOdmoOBdGJT/f6NQd@q2BtxUsY1hB1DA4vkzUdToY@Vs7OEPgFxggIB8Gnsga7E4SZrIaqmgnT2g4DXGBY56xhp@ZFnFfvpfvBuwSRz1HbBRQKwII3cMiQTbBhwU9h391NaAOn7oOhAnCSvShyBHq3Iu34oDJK12F05oqVVIkV5IUZBPQjuxq7WpRAn@oisYVr0gxL/36j2Z/40tnvw/9YnXuqcHyAaMqRLsKbsMEFsLvLoRVVq9F6hVyoGzpluHCyLXP@VN/tIZktpRAzODpYBG8M3PSHSYild9N8vqhY6iiLVbCpjCv1aCI8xrvlrxfBCjlCA@jeX60edAQ/PicgACMzMpohh9tFo02q9U44WCzNdHOIpmcUSZnPAoPPVuTyZYfDaSng2B4weppAXeK@0RFgKfyYRTYoLHIPP3UwAX416gPFJco/DQXNIdagd@GkMXGdtZtrUy9Ecl0hGhdAYAN8RqAHv@Ae0W4SvBUKbSFNIqjMqBR3OY3A04roIERCa5yndmJsJGRDAwMv5iicQD6rphqCKJK08z4y/BbTAeOwa1ed8wsh1SXHTPpK79/EMcWYjbSQSPch5rJIUFGSeaF7SubjfIcMbY7BQEHuLrOmcMSK5htcFemflSlYzkdZaTjRhr8rDN3lcfzZCA/4EINuzd2JvrEyeUqXGgyqdmtSp/LDObAdvBrcBG9@cDr9RzDs@MTqNT/t7uv224bV9a8Np8CkZ02mVB/TuwkcuSObMuJdid2ju0kO@O41bRE2ezIklqUf9RJ9jrnXMwLzNzPI8yrnHc4V/MUe@qrAkhQkmWne8/sWZPVbZEEUCgUCoUCUKhq9U97URz6Ci5NP4d62RHqSB6OrSfrx37sONqkS5axAC18BVW32Yx60ajZdGEp6VUSe3E2nAR7Li87WP/Sk1WexJMGujdw@ye/hq2RdztMBIHQxQ6j1md3b6AT4XujpkiGtUj/p9Qz0mBU3E9XjuxgHqr0ycjl6CVn/fP@KWl9F3EB@7DOBPhGChsIBYMB4@KrAEvaihUKhEeJ2/IDTxf96buLqp9W3MBLyq9kAWSI4avhJI1B2eGM6po3VifFTH0H34/vgY3vwXx8eRU@ibMszauS@H1VP3JTCJQxRePR7Wig6SS32lPoZFBJPkOvkgJ3RrHNhmptYFqjrDWdvdAh/vCTt5jeEsTf30T/@R1oitfv2n0BDXt1MCZ5cw6bT5cDeMbmvNWl7A0Psme6uoS1t@9YF@VF7OQdqBCkxrLg6sE3Ng1MRFuKkw1kA/gWnodt2BTfs8FYVRJn4DS89NXnlZu7aLvZDrvBOGy7OqdvwTUt3qcFG8uruzUcgo6FXl/Wei7NXV6SStM4iC6ZKjewTOBfet7NbCVZooR7eKecMWzcTD@kT4lmbPFVZbea1gHLy4vYjr2MsP2JKFMSfqEr0Ru1HJX5R3oSrjRuJwjRQWbPsp9W680Tn/tu0qQ7zAhJ3kK2yfCObiDC0dV0H34fiW5vKXWuVahqetnJBh6a3ePRvB63uMLwpBw73Y0lb2O6O/OcxWoCLBVhW983hUxBhpFIq@XaEOXL3B7r96ZkAr7xPl3vhlmlOUOgJiVZ0o0iXm6zfuE5WBk36BcbTu/pFwBPw1FTGMq0DXtaOiCy4pTzYGBpLfoLKekExaKikFyjYeVyzDNl//ItqbN1Y52tqTpbmTqTEZCt0srktDJV6l5A98zrgm7YGd0gnZGEtTP9zBPb9K/XD4bYrfiyHC1XIl8tXy5XSCAvh8uVuktCebm9XNnmh3i5csAPn5crP9FDOraWvy5XzLBAhiG98sMLfNciHO@t5cqW631zRsHnMDb1FpYrSZ9Snh/llSlCpEC7SWvEEVuvr5s5GoY0sbFS6StwTOxj@cT7MD7/X6L/JJQYBxlCIvY4H3Bm9VCVM5OGNWNIPTRtmCAWM0ZyRc/m9b0dNrJKsqCah7TGs8sweFLDF5ezwkgQQyqfaNAvIQi5WZmNkbJmsjuio2snDuVOztYvUQ5ZH2i7nH5EmY/TSjh@nC5v@isLQjrwbnii8E14TqFjqmOMcCbrzUALRP1leU6j0NdZXHTv2z3Ee93ZTIRt3mSRXmKwlkwnHY4P5zhOZH@QZRJOhbl/ZJfhTTkZlODeiWIsFfTIvCGZP@uWQTDYg9@b1xyrHFDLiCAkHpWOZZQl8wLLYiSlss7SVGXwEQqWzKERHrY@c2y@bf3I@UTc@DxX3DQNmbJSJUuurJikwgW4BrsIRlJ7snitw2HY9y1fTclr7LW4AGCVTGoR@dr/Dv29L/q7UagNESYqmKVYz55Kp9XrubPsBObdtNrpDkSir7a9mcpRUkNKclodWJr5PF6bUvFh8iFKvlSaQJ/Q9g3ZkjXBLXSbXFsILGgJw8vsx88r9PHzys2EmtZIupcFo7QUUJOGIw1PME2bNh9XafisLkYK728H3e/u4GG2g@3OAzxuwHCC5DLKhxc9tnJJxzaJbfkCkVquKBHkfFyadHP6kcQ9H90mx7b0Ya@5v723@/ojTbpPnjzx9Bw9TvHDqMVeazKPC2S22E7mgxnLlhUfAbRw2I3t@PisPxzd@9TLTckSEdakDARUi2E/PcY9LcsseT4xdqmc5LUoqmF9TodBkJFKUHUCTNmRpuuICBKO3AeBBmLUW6K3z6s1j0NFNZu94DxsNnn6MsHc9SyGrjEn4t7fF@8VL@IhBy2XOGdXjsOuM9T2nvrwqnaoDl/V1c67rZ/Ux7136kNt9xBOEN6@23zd2FL0f333oK6cjCkeYkJiQUl03Q5bISL9qpVS6bFiyFv9wVjkjrvlyfeD4Fy96rdCHFM9j4PzF2fyUuiFow0pVafl6Bh7mBHHAD2PRrC34KCVtIyFctPmK4q4YqAo7wmtac@x5j3vt6NORHkdrH0HURibW22qG1EPkrw1F7t9UZIQn5JNhzjuLCywrqh4QPlxdkNgArG/AomRQwJatgtKEy75990UPKzvvzlQ8Kextbe73Ths7O0eqJ29fXp9@7Gx@5Lo2Tg43G9svkMSZ3yzt93YaWzV@IMgUCooOLr49SIezUWhgOxMldZnnHwXBtT9yVt21xsavLoK@LJmrJYvepA@UdCNfg/by@vORQz1BRdE@ahAuUu1/Zfvac5X4W844TRHwWx/kHsXc8zUpZJ6zrXRYNmg8bauhytNe/myx@cR52OFsEnhOjvAcPnZVwY4G/G0o1DltmCjgr1v8ZPBY9mAporuEWyAMgYrVcXhzpaX/ecMcoNqa3X7cLcqtYkRoX5B0RfG1GTdYYppWxkAxSWKRg/7QeX15APxPX1Y0dWOhpJBPUo@SAb1WD5AFW3AdkSt6hwXo70LiGe1Jh9@PR/s8LGwepJ82Ax4FftU4yT9xl0aqCRcJLyGdDmonezycOBdcQKDIjHnR8C3blcGRiihRkkmylEi27ZRzhwJmw6OGrTZm4TwRipxA@yEgs4oVm7VK6hDGAeFvUjCCZ52g56YQKWmO8x76ik8OlX1XfAoCcPH11IGfWZAhADN4pGU29ZaYXjXclRyc6rGQNtIcihcY4J2GwKbUwj8ETAEKJ9Z6bR4puL7swDT72hWduM@cST2bf9m5yd2bl@0wkwBbbXl/hr9/runiexn1knGTpGxoy76PRySWslHmZ3@kMY4i1UOXAYp2DrrD0aR9KGbbQGfOPE0R7kxsVFtv1Q3MrWBDpM19vo9q9IT4uIbaj0hprxLrczxcnaeiK80ojVxPk3CYncHdIKT/mVonZ35OES6CrH9Qoown5Vj83M8YkxE/3RS2fE3hUC4T6sb25uf8n/7xUc0XBELEozaGB3if2JM1EXDg8/52GBxCL1LjzQTxTC@OEFpbYOnpSVGuQFG68CziNZ1L5rrSZqYG09/x5Wdye/88evXqpTKQzLpCObxmZtKN18dmSp9LnOstAmIJTsJWZL1rvniM8xEXr/ANR30AjwO9SBHsG6fiBGoRYhp3clFhySLDtWsuzuB76kNtqhI49zj@o3dH8Wf3c3qww2vmBqUKIucrhHRvoFc9jzLLIXnqylw2/PBkfy@O7inc7GT6eG7oG3PhfZduOUf3gxLpiUL1t3B/m0OWJnc/hBYart/M2CZJKehJZyeMKe/tJhY086v8ZepvuOxR2Aw92IHJQFq1XbR4yNq47zclQKeDSZViA4Ot@v7@yon6xMqS3IPS4a2FoOAfU@9Ta1tox4Lu0KiNCWL5UR5Ml8yFm3m37zBPJN4N4gKrYP4mh6JsEhdpHeia5F6emZhFYKt71kgGsplsftiZFB8pAF/ozUgIZt2mtVAZ2YzF2XyiWLbCFzTzRfd2LbhZwtrmbsRAHk4tgHZNkHBKW6WzO6/D6IfV0w9omDB2xIa3CZNmuYbWiccUMUDylgoZHtwTreYLoWRvSjYi4Z2MPwqZTXsP89QzEiihIsubIl1rRxr1EQ/XjJqDhskYhoIYOmpE8WimRKMiOcvz@0O9dJJz81OQaRkIiTuC5srqPjxNz2FMTWSebKaKOT2WFtibI4MlsfYndWw12/OdB@20GuT4mGyKpK2c6vK/2OqklkiU5Oh@czGmESCvLa6@ug22JOtMMXzfxa2zCGT8nN0PqD1fQoyHse8vU@c29j1TXrKAHNIJ6b1ZsBMFCRVZ8ackmk7T0Y2foSL7AsRMggAgCjDk7V66noCt9nQZUayoXOWqTZYQzhpqIyaKep/m18dBPKt9d37/vpksCETTAe/wSr/TX8Yh@mtPMtvjPUJ9@2z38LhsMfZ5D7TOaC4fI1p7mU7vm0nBq/SKiTyeZvdko6@nSRmt77Za@BKeHuxgMDi2N1bn9zey5fX7abuNF7X1QP2s9nJ7EXmhjnPkj33ot48BFgG874Epg@@w3c/rtD/hINvQBKZ@Dafy7TxbsWNKUJa8xGHhNJmoVq2lid7vxO3gh48jfi5@7HK@T9QQd6Fre/teLN21kvrmfKEXDzouVTKz@ULOS5K37ChC0hZENKb@G5NWLipYSwlcb3mtA/7KBxshdeye8aWk0Gx/LS09szh1vX8kX9@9OzYf9Cq5hRNvkHvPL4YXrU/n/bPLjuqqwa/nly3xr//ptTqY3jPVis/iHfk8lq1yP5lnyg41n5WYs7VCP7Inp4R6LogEYCVWlbpOnz9nvL4gRfNFdyQmOBS9eDccCGu2I2q50drx9VetbR@ftQ7Xsclv9HD6uhh@aGLDz/QLEoyRk7mj0bHmFPtXdewd6ngUpQjzeqrIYqvhtCXN8Ew6r@u7b7M7MZBAcAWmLb15g11CSq@AGs23D0p9MIrV2@T@Qoc60BBchb4VlAZ99x5PxnbMe2IMKNe8Umbja/579hzFkqFi8GozynGDyRYS32NvjoL5hpTiXcUKMtRZLxF4n4BwUnzuDgYkq9jsaLOl0VdK@PupGeBOEJJFoe5T7kc7hQCUX2X6@jYiQth0DoDEl1Sq79yMfX8ucIbsVpc4F08mHIEQ74wUTrGIw5A6GfApw2ogjX3mK99ONR8vJfxIF94j2rE92TYQN5hTREpMP9WX/h@E5d/TgQQwi@IzlXQW5xa8yJFUu4O8uYCnKxlF/44ZsC1SumUBTQWsKW@agqcLcWZRqhWk4m@L1yBnEIr@qdbkC/z21QzkvyeZGeS8Dm1fotBS@5STtrATzct5lrF8qaYyWyRYuFWamCni5ZHb0IaVmO1FXa7hLTQYiElBx75fq@u/2FSf3yEOo8T5CU9P5Wez6QXJF2QSnMVaIJPM1XsTLnFL2m@byqXZvOn6qoqVl4K1NOtAqkkad71eXnjwqjfjNLMG0lXClcmCc8zCXkr5ecZvS8p9zJlEgZP0o8kXfP3iu75BMtM3hfZ@vHr6A4K2XhW25pMcGmhF3V/dHQAdp0CNssRNZWS4hwPU5lBVdV3MLU4IQ0O@/w8bDeqKZSHZSNxeMzkNp6/yBW0kvGjO4mG3GKcGlgzxohFJa7zIRPumi8sUj2cfM8CwTDBaMqM3A1TeKwLjy2wyHXPVCu3IKcGODVtcohXcS/yK/6YwZ5FzuRbnJ24IJhfS@PldnOWQCx07@VmkykrTXBdRD7qRs2ZRdK6x5MQZwuJXWsXOKkzlDvYHWyD30vkhC0ojKSYonuSoimdZigb9r2pC5H4zfl78YHzMiAde9ANr1UNy4yAb2E5mQvuozAexfA1xW5w4ovBoItTR1b4rvgKtXb4v7KK45YUojWzF5wGLHskv48nfSGdChXUHiBfwUAkTYgvTk9xmQw3YPtXEK3YcYlGBafWG8uGBo2ZRytyzTxUcL7BArgbndpISM/J6AGl40HQCgsO6WgxaT@ONLUT6TCyvJ@OeyNwaUZTWsVx/uUian3eeonz3Cfl0qOyRbJLfRxcKjx6nF6wIiKZhBV4JVwtP3Yc62y4JWfDeQD01WtM9O@JN8PLsNcLnRrNGJwxJqU1DoeXYbvgOPthcggMuGBlnEziHnb/YtiSzR1SugJiRtwSjn05DiMOwy/mZzkubvFZme/g0Co9baauvozaIKC5cdLp43SYDyzgJkDogULn4YiI8sBTWZT47FnjwrrLOTaiiBrwc2KdTSRk6PVHUYt6hneynC6BkmOQtLJeewITqq/VDXA5uDALAVyPSSlgEDBHSfNwcPSh@XfhoHTDzBl7YHqmSNKvz2OFhns4jEj6pgTmXuFiFu7UwYevGgfqYG/n8ENtv67o@e3@3vvGdn1bbX7kM24clLMHYPVq7zVJl@Q0XU7N9@hDrnZAJXOc4NR2P6r6X9/u1w8O1N6@arx5@7pB0Aj8fm33sFE/8FVjd@v1u20@fScIanfvUL1uvGkcUrbDPZ9rNcWctJza21Fv6vtbr@i1ttl43Tj8yDXuNA53URlO9WvqbW3/sLH17nVtX719t/9276Cu0DBnu3Gw9brWeFPfLlD9VKeqv6/vHqqDV7XXrycauvdht76v2EjAauVmnbCsbdISFjVxO7cb@/WtQzQofdoi4hGCr3118La@1cBD/a91ak5t/6OvgR7U/@UdZaJEtV17U3tJjXPcW6hC/bL1br8O90mgxMG7zYPDxuG7w7p6ube3zbQ@qO@/b2zVD9aV83rvgAn27qDuK0Sn5KoJBlGL0ul5891Bg@nW2D2kOePdW9g7eNTJH4gwhGWNim4zgWEGgdYSkfb2PwIq6MAd4KsPr@r0fR80ZWrVQAVYVGwd2tmoQiLiod1MtVt/@brxsr67VUfyHsB8aBzUPeqwxgEyNGCQ8ZFYhyp9x61GPxFe8kjM6hjO9bk7VWNH1bbfN4C5zk0ccNDQ3MJk23qlaV6A/19rEyXqY88gOLc3VjrTny5DeLyc3pGZvUeTeEza2tuu04ysnV3l0oR3NOs8nXClZKfRTJMk0mvGZU07PLk4bUa9Th93TJNisvFxHp/6CIXkISzMJ2dOJDK9v8IFFhebzfe1Ji10D5pNz79LyQwat5XQ2@Dzcnm6jYj@gJU3Nn4qFaH78wyhNn7QB51sqIcDCOQU6v8gpm/BeeipYrEd6mK4vA/AZusolmOTMxylkGjky46IZ5NWyTsT/B5pduCCrgFfaDWxTwrLSM7Uj@lP72v6IpOD9YGks2x3FYtYxDIa0e@hqUYqYZcI/Ed7JIg6XGUhDsPPp27Jrg5r/sJpv992Pc@U4bwjWgeeut4txU/C04ni@cnyjCwfO@vACbFZd7MKk5w/a5Ip3S@FIbfMxZ/miH88g434fMCuKVfFm9V609L9QYrDIslX2rUFrldwJ0Pne1P7a@MDVnOllcfrE99fJd9lbMFeEL5xacI74nLH/PPqWDLQAGNfHESSSHvIKBatMsbeJMl8RRnPkOkqasPyh@bqs5DndSIJKbIXQdeuE7PxMLq2sSc5/HK/9mbz3c4OiU5g@/jp6pO1dSdxu/VXX34/oh52X8texwY0j5OexknWKNkixYdHiuU9PGV/ZuBiERnhOd50Gn@En4fEbiNryQRBhubGCO7Ug4leLgQdcoodcNxzDL/OHJmaAdxMUz205jy4ZhU/IF2JeUAbs3TH3GvX@APYyfA3QzxpkGYgzWLs0Jc4l1YXLPdyO8ZUlBc37LgHWQo5w8fixi2hAW91sf0sbtfym@ZtqxdjMWXEeOVu55KExL1JLJSxq@jJyH7Lfkb0BjB7D6Mvf9X8Ro8ftYM7dncXxKPa6IDIuJOUxD51uhmtG32kIR8jkgecqpmanivs8nsaKR57ejs5cQxijQZGBWFpYOObBbye@BGZrJItYF8se@qLcCqcdwDOuuZY/U6cO6s5Gsq68R@i341XCiWwEicnQrWrpA7HZPmY@LEw5MyQ6U/Rg@H/E2kyA/5zWnES9JRalhPAO1GSoQqtaPnKRImuzEGDdbqRUtP@9DEF883umLOkYfr05lru1xAJdO@MzYeP7Paw484gAJgcGxv2@E1M0s4CWjq9yHm6OM5Jeq3zgav0XGGmiim4@bVjn9Uu35yt4MVTnuw1WRW@pqLqhSzcTnjU05JpYimv7sc5AecZ/x/FB7wBkgx45tIzsVqd5KySHmVGDmhXS9aE0048JpFa@u3GU7sHynKRmZH9@uTLEIpAbwCf6XZySJO@EvPcrMdFnonVIXvBg5NyLJMx@WiXdSdsiNkNAed@mzdDEPVkdIUJoivQ2VVfCk2599lQBJWkVoepn0GIW69ApOVp9SrBnncmwaEJ9u964h8/lF0tk6MgDj40hvZ1@YJ6E4wJ5e7dmi0sVnxw0Pdhu4jKZFtCl0eEl1a/PyTVMUC7CUc/GnsF9UFvOoS9@GKo/RfSfBYN9Y6EUfqpGqhNsnrnaUYc0zNqcTTCbYV2gfmDm3QewkJU3JNc59eUS8xreHTDbDpG1w/Lyn2epjwnmrBbUibic7Wmvn6VXEJQ7TI0ZApGcbK4YJtNrgfnDsnwu@oPP2PuhwrUa4ftxDOpBZL3AqWTGj328dgaSdMH/Zh3NKgrsAOSUKIsG2mJoSrN0U80O2m7plzqHRO@S7kl319PwqTGWooqShlX107Mt5anzgSVVrRr0MRZaHlllVGZteD6duNijL2FZo@tVe5TLxEpFVEiqveN6ognkZvJ00c86U3@6v0Yo4e@4Ixbq6BAGDorzlWn5RzjB5uCD1E4bNt7oqTJtIMBtt946dPvMS@arUPt9q8VjOJwTCuAVjG6LjKMpvuX/lmvudXvBqdRPwponQav8tci8fA45kd02OmwfxVz8CKJyGhlao/TZ/EvI27Y8J6cS65brrniUThwbTOF0XBcOxM3EbxzDiPANOIq8/dg0kdaUubxalrIyd4/ZXu8srd@Y9lH5VmF5UQfALSA25iwoJA7pCO@mGRdPl2fynAyL4OF44nKq8C7wWIvg/EzIhEfw2QwNshMmSXYjcDK7EaMj9rXfpt9EA7haCncDhFmJ3b5sx8g6jVJkR9hKVBR5aclq6icolzDDyEexjeTe@XJPxl7QuBPoF9@NItbZjECi7iO8bYUy3pFexklXNg8MGIZzZKYpFh0GvWs64cc0@J6Emo2eXwTNdjyh5Qi7WZviisxIl1a@CDGntskkdMce5hUltWyx347oILURm7pZoYNb7Of5cGPQ1zZOYNg2tKQXQvpm0jVIiohTPCEea2NsvhUvn3ErKzctdcmCFidZXJmxbd2c0Zz4RsokcyvONbqD0kY5yaop009luNRf7B8R@rdKDtmemabReuW591qCCzMVqXJ8kGbSVsd43G87kziM8E0WYqxpRnxEJav/Jyw@SQRr6tNjLdqc3wLHW6iWWo3lUwqSX@3ZexjUryERa@ZaJIhxbjDSel68v2oSQ1v3ixBNExZXjVZYjQhMppjebRATZApodLdKcTcp3GfoEebKId620Q7u39uJOqkkZxxeWqSMk4uQU84bselTZJLgw6ML@AmTjTcREglCue1P@ajvHL@BE6GkSAAoRWH@XQfSnZw086a4COODtBxm7AWKkMS0dOGbeGQOP1PCMZe@fXmjrZ4aI7z5eN1gXSdQKJVBeeaB8ncN6fXo@Y1Q5kiBQ3xGaRIWjQlm87u3qo/2xbKRxCkNCdrS9@Sj8Z46iFhQ3/spOY1dOC0Kl0yM6KyA6HJooHGAq1STruhLFeh/UVD4XhYN@hhRAsI@ezi56EuAXfea6WE2ihy3R4ji6fJLaPNU/kNKZIylLyD/HooiqrLC1cCEArGVL5aJghwa8rY41CAXe/YnJdBVPcRFayWMSzpI3tFTe08Z6SDqDrD41UrR2lWjmc2jPxMIKRYzM6TIkI6y@wsKRSa6GbiYuV4Mrs9aQ5SiA3vC8WpK3SvZGmY9JwQkMNcl7xUohyVlV/SHMyJj1e9TGLC35z6rGSlliZTiT4Jhkf58mTq01ImNVPtykq2aKYk0cOza80kEik8G@FEKvy5f3w1xXZ5ntiEWouMjJah7bMRhpxWmbRuK/waq@d8KdvoGAaefTPcLL@aEmIl45R9vgN2tcxHBvDd/qdbayxTDSY6VgD7pTOXXVxZELLGmsNUj2ZhpWs87SUOCsyatt9R7w93djJuX0/GxtDoPByulkolMPGJ7fze2FZjKynqF7O5i52Lbrc4uPrL8P1JkWV/GHJIgIpZQYfUJTQo4kJ/eCqRIYADZUXuvL7IirX@Radjh2DACSU6j7pNcmpvCIonoCgxenl/yBtADFJPsL@ggWjfLyoZfVeBKJoaijmGotIwCb7MmdMzIg8@dGCfnZxUMTAIZmPNRPOWV934ghkEkU24s9h9sfclNU/OvQq73b6vPiD8MTwFLHybLLCzYxcoSRacMPLt3ouY/dH6KryMuta9YmSxeR3gzMRk4kwYv/Dwjb8fntavB27u6OccTSvU5Ido5kP4p/ZV7jTnaWfxdwArfEho3yn3eTBwW0ynycw01esRnD4RRo/K/sy1TyaLx3timma35wZRZ6NbYGcN1HSPdQHjy567l1tyQ/aEuLlP1@UOaFgSGBon@Fy5WwlcNfvnicXLUadzN6nIYQCkY79LIkoklD8nEPkMgEegHn5ET3jR/ilPw3pnwqGIKDgI1jEtd1CgiQKOc79V/e3KrdVqamnw8KGq1TbpIZ9Xtc2a2saHzU21Te@beP@hurK6ui4yd9v7Qh83zcdvapNg8A7nw9bZcJteKa2Ke2Ow1kYXLxWrS/76UrP6fGM9Lh7VNnGtn57@89/@63/@@38r1vTL/8DLJr8c/ZxkKhQKxaXWl6Ufvq3j/Wj7eHnp5GhpcLx8ug4u@zt7De83RvkgNR8tDE@cRZkFrK9sR2rW2ex9RhdVJqbfeTD8TNKlohZbcXFRf40lchTL2MVWaH0PcY/yhJbwJujA5FKekFgkoGNsx1PvtEIY4NF8Q5QkXGAHKuXlbMVs3MMdTJIhOVVZ1J54WGe9DHGnJfWkgLu4NGPlo14c9rADfsk6rzTPcQL6jUZNzb/Fn9/Ep5v9a/Xgk6selNQDXz3I5finvPaMvnpLxQi3cyUbLQdyOZ9S0qMFmBmqOGJFj9cPHGtngtyOs8QhewDJuKngzHILzk9Wf3xZRgKuxafOAiJ7Ktki4UMmFFn8stT7Rt3yhXJ8y2Wu2rCi0NSrGK7MOlFJ@hcqUBCLIUBa87kQpNKnKnHSxzeS8VQ0X3RfOxxNiAGDrPsvd3jc4wPNRUs9bfOcWUshzBGbz8tXzI3rchma0UaK1J8iwAcqspws8U3C5cVlR6y8rVZyM@UWtt0@zXxi6zAOR8Y2XQr9TVlMINbcNuGWevpeizbkluMVlYuS4xWrqtyk7bdyrCLnF91RNNDXFbh2DKgvSW3fZCShRxmQwBGf/ZXpEcYbBcZT1ES3SLCssWr30XQZCT19NZ062CvIyZFFhOLPLo3trxNj2yvyLRHDDsIDjFRiytcJom6sva4MmdinwfAE0QGDDgdUG8m5Ge/nIULrBMb9ToJ0gSGzyXk6nqkpi4NhcHoe@Gpxt384DMYNmrZI8xm1Ch61EC6YgAQGn656VvMMwtIi3SVMkaQpbDmE4AXdsQ6PJn2bS@6coEvNUNBuVzAIMuzElAy/Zvpqgo4pV39HJ9goTwnv5DRSi1iWvLA00pBy9rUZHmZTQ8cxNdhjJxk4OUdQTUam4QVd6AIT7Tkf/JIk78JHgK47p28B6qsIa89QP2an07AXZCanQdcxF/2L60rmRYxnDkUp1kiOhvKknEa8A1akR/6c9QIhc5NxZ@QsuO7Cp1iHc1u05xF28p3Y4hcDFSUB6DiAGd8MUe96kQjLiRkqjYFRUA22/CcInW5wSviNr4IxWPHTovvjvaJ39POn3vED91Pv66ffPcZEi2Qzy@bVoj7MNhJLjxWaGYt@5tVYpcXG1eCnXjbDp56SOywWCQiRonv0c/H4a5EQ@rSIUPefFoUgmS4DJsX59RUBvjiF5mIWi@Kis@A98Eznuz@WPUVzK/@iD@WDJ7@EhVlU8jY9rXOGHQLF93R/u5ArJ3Hx6Urp8Ur5Ma2ETsPr/DC8wHybjy9OwmtSJWIsZ2nq@fR7hhsyhPh2HQfr9PGa2ilhTeTuSawvKWkRqoc51@MkbEVlCsITlJ@ozO5SccXFS/IEOHzEgt9XxHImL/uCEtNBi/tczJ9x/xz1BDHk2uTtEOFIWBmIjQhvoeYB2QRfuYlDPTNclvmeU0FtwXcrA6HuLS5as0Wv38trZc0rLK9Dicatme7T0tPS5BidGqKZEbqklanle6q88eOT//jve78tjhY3VoofhvQ7Wvxtce3pojzSA709Mm@XixuLz5Ft7dviuEhrYHp88h//k8pv/IXgIGX8nP5srBpYa@PFjXyVi3xd3Fijh/LKCtX7v/71X6kNS7JiQyzWpaavGLF1Q5GtoMe8S@mqgVbKsnQ5FSt8MQswxMKQ1ub0AsOo65WnJd6mW9RWFZeh9nxl7FH0FM@GWSM2FZKdDGNPQZqRFKiigryANCYUHWXZbhizDTBviqb65X5hLaYVwC/anCOpMjHduB/DZGhJlkXUga7USOt5edgo/ZhLzDsqOWNTsm5USCzttKx9@mid2OFtPxxFrayVhBmu563gKjwpgA8LYfuC1lS9uNv/dVi8JJY8L688LXawuV9kO@7igCHlB@PC76QI6mBAtDBko1NfDakH@udw4eVztCBS6HeSMykTT5K07EHYkj2sbExiyiJ3/Hw5HkZzCqkq7fJfUuAROVMHgrRipX3qUcm9/YrKPUwySj5e83rA5i0bx2oXGHmxhh2wbCo43AbsDpr2FGrDU76ExKXgdV2yFIJ2uxnoNNdZyJlQab6zcBZ2B9VcR9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNvBFKPsIOQj7Pgg6wzsNRQEv0ao6/YD2e1gA3KfqsNXEVl5K1o/PqVX27ylFX5lR9JVVfUY9CS0jrSXjG8sam7GwiW6rYqhyGTRypzayYaotN0OZhgX@AQSzd0ujgWoJuDt@AJKqlzdFWZXa3@bwWJh65CuXOnmwtSuRqZzG9/OibHHKDGroT6i1IZSQg4AW3Agtlej@QGxBVE2Y06jniz28i2fj30GC4DXtwJWq7rRPnozIt9S4R@yYa8V1KRSTQfmVtG2xHZo8EdOJiKwlBm8PGS84DS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEyuVkn@qopZLwsh0dvVYCRdCHXKm88ujx6tqTp88Q5WxBt3Y2GBQqYBUwOAsIBmvULi2y8b1azS3n5BNCUE9XCeizwOIADmZdV55n3D5fefeq5ZIGVsoxrCsOoyHF9XYlg0whDsMCZgRao7jDnOv@WDlCw44/tb2v9D/xt/EPyAxn3NEGQnqrH96mnqmcc3E4UGXBzE5x3EfwoOLpFDtv2O/sw9tECFtXYXuq6DU8QIzOhv2L0zObOwratdUhDRgiOPulxgrqZThKHYxZWEEX1RsODev2RdXAO5puAYxyMSVA5xPgNMy038pAW5pidCzTJATPmrixiiNEy3TUZmfmzl5f1Xe3JxFbtMPQMdyCbdlKyh17MoMDGcTqtZp7SNTV3i74KqmWSX7GqzILuBLylfk6fIC70i0EoraoYmQ16w0jdx5ZysyLqWvTtCj1I/CaAbNcup2U5l6raQUIYgSh3k1KhJifnOfYJEtxsjsZ4xS8nKtYNqJvojhmB3O6spynLUo5E0cVWHBuAIh9m1JOGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIScr1XBmTg4zwVa3sTjARtRxQwu0v7G75avtOv3Z@bDtQ1HerP2Edichnm/Gt6zxLVdUY8d0ge0tlm1uYTP1G64oEbOUtMPYFEEI345ERQxTrwH1xo6mvQzqo8zYPk65AuwaaCXc7I7qQQJHL7wHsqAX74krDr6uw98qsnk1LWkSlyp6WMgW1/yBbdFkIa01gSSkvAOIlUkQiaOWlNsXUoYXC3TWvAO9djGM3diZzdMZlpUFFantO0Uie5Znb6TMPLZY0WyxUkE/zuML5tu5vHESdvr6LlrCHLfwxr0/xhv5uzNH/v8L5qj/c7jjkeaORxXIHuGOxG043@jkMOz9GRxzMuY5uNmOTiPsD3WsVzSi5FsAWOABQ9whpcRyCW27QZwod3bCw8n5CEZCK6u4GPCHGv9YN/5xBTKXH7fD/1cbn/8HN35VN361grlmRs9r1c5yt/6PaXGqErrZDzO7F@quZPP@aEvXdEvXKphNZ3Tz//WW5v8PtfSJbumTCjwmyIGDuK@fz82iidQOthqN1Nyi4GinXS7i2M/mSg9rr3Y1R4uHTvciPqtCW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OItIbEOTtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStdj@gJSoQ0b2wN9UKFFHJfEtPTpkKqP6bSN5l87oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZS8d4qL56iCZK2vJvLLNPpDV1uH@64f/RchwHnzWt9AIeXTtVdjtmpnEXoIdJl6ndGOs5gD2gV5zZFhFk5ORHenb3gm7LNws1dixxcS8OHuRIEdtOP@jtdQ59A0rKje2jIg2BV3erKpgmmuWF/KF2i6ZZjdZt/gPcekzzaXPKmpfLwxuIlWgN/w0L6brtJXV1XlzgJQq4AcDsORT/jmj6n8D)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/9ckue)

IronPython is separated from CPython with `-b is -b`:

```py
b=2;print(-b is-b and+1or 394)
```

`+` is for Moorhens.

Answer (score 2):

## 397. [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers) v2, 16600 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)1 1>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                 2222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&11# 11 393374366369375377370285329364392367372376289368371388   389284373
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 2
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[




























































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::PrasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t"F ._#^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4oya:nlet d=/;~ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'7* 001- #vk!>6*+'P:3+'D'34#v({427aa364-1264-49e0-be04-f7cd28369fde}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L39c@NKciD448TA@0eUQHWTFAmAAL9JkWq1Wv1ab7pbPWr1e8@PZLNBEiTRAgE2QEpkS@qYmb2b89jePe/seGM89vqNZ8974/NGrG/j9jy@tXcj7Ptxw7E/@Q9of1xcOC48/8FcZhYAghIp9RuvIzbuIBGoz6ysrKqszKpCoqN7w5/9LIYXe@ZY84HlTNjE8Cas55qnhiuz@3N2Tze9vJYVBEy16w6mI8OeeBUhxlTGLN0eTPWBwfqmNTHcNPMMg3UMyzmDeI2x7ak99YxeHXxZxmzjjB3YXbMHENjEOTFs863hQlyOsQeGdTG6mLCuMxrpds9jY9e0JxSbZ@yZDp7@tHvC9I43cfXuxHRsiCow9sK29FGnpzNKPnYNnqnIAFT3hPIsx5QYe@K4ngElOF3D8xwMLEOg7prO492nH11Jr2bYRzogNbaM2ZXiVZV9ahpu72oOjX1y/PDh1dAs@5rk2OzhdZTUHNudTpyDyVX4ebY7MGydaXJZ1q5GFoCYE8MqZUqZq1FFaE9jYnaXyoGIh6YLrav7rci6ug2thW25xYzReDJnEm9/3bLCtvWY7rGpN9UtSmdPRx3DDRJ6E92dmPaAnZmTIZsMTS/MR6m9sd41pJ5hmSNzYvSYZUImp@9DAdB2j50Y8zPHhSb3YTq2NYeMRtfsm5glwAMA4pWYDA0OZ6TPoZHtCXQOpjMP0LCMAFpSiEH6B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjg1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadaBOCAyhZ8NDdvvzABOBhDHDsfq9ZRQMxZ9Xu/1WAb6MeBxYjATqEZoVVg2C@HMcYFqkCrAyAdG/ZrX0ZhBm0ET9Z0Ky2cyEL8fhiC2uuU5PjLLqGGkDWOV2gzhPnOdgauPgBo9g2j6ycEz5nUdF3zww7R8PN0EpqtP2PY2i@8/fRBn9bBZZLcjhE1UY@fQBLEgkp3q1hR6SLQlHGgfN8wtYJPFN@IVFgeyaBmWy7EcDNsS0/JAJDVTBgeMfy2rwq/AtBLLqTCC8iyrFeNpLKvv6gPTMjikAUIqYueHJBrcMzmWVUs85cCx@jxZlwossmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYMSEXyOqeU8/ArwA2hlQEeFXzbHAS36PvRV7G97rK@PTGvuQyfwXZZXWREgAs4qQNZKAAGe2Sz@svAjtJavKOzJECg@1E8BvGSZJ8iRjJApYTMq8FC2thTiish2efHeEIsH8gHh8iVWhOILQIkcoADU1UpQfD7DK@INDcvysw09zEbYFjPwA8yLQIcStEAGaJlBYhbhB37geRowNw04mQbMSQOGomngzmIRkK4AcQVozoJPr6HunUBBvBytR8QHrg5gVKQ2MjIViQQQoLVYFtqswHLQGbLYGfJZBvgDLsUCA15WUlkpx0pFBvQsZxi0jQp4YU9RgYeqgI@KwKD9VegAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjzkzUJeII2agzw5cEPDqQX8QT7oGSoUqUKZmlZedETATctDffNZ6qFaAVq3CHFANw1w1aA7aYCtVoJ4zFsCGpawA0O35YTQkQ7QKtjloR8CMfKAD8GFtODWillOP90aD/UOcmyes9PHrAUcCgUkI2TNYPXgmUNqAioZAIOjANDXoAdkacTAMxcWb6kApIHgjZ5JTNoygX@pIYWKaeqQr/XxZEE2tUAYjeeTYRim8TAHmKcJDNAY6N15GAmjLx1GLkILWQzViN8uAGVyGOoBd3WmnrUAEjpyGhVlnJrWIqxEYT1D7/VNb/hugWuOCukY@sQ2Txal5PPpCFH1SEQBI5aCitlo2okpwZQ1GKJrURetiGnGTthASyirKqHXMfpTe2BI5VIEP4qZTN0JTC6LMss82DUHA5iXF3DUNFWTJstFcJ4wtLLZiRAGInWxTNeEKfwu6w5BqAgjyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4MwugSQGM0EZ566@OWOdu12aORYIZolO3aE5DhJX1iaONC4VMisVIn2DKPe2lAlZM14t@bVj2ok4iyeFSwHmGy5dRmdrmNQ@xZkK517sujC3OiQ5LNhnwg5mxyQQbXmih5nXAjYKjdLVcRbGOcmgOTWAY05kBoWAKGg4pyi60sS4VIxHk2fHRUkVJJ2e4boM04J466VpmvWmHc94M0VZaoFXH@ZtA6b3vm5aIQI0j@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@mAWlsVEz2nv0iGxhAdhBa@6ihYpdfVGA8pioQKXSbC7S2DpTCKnTHcyKLEFvk6DuOjOE9x/CoszjuSTj0sTDPGNDQgHHWXzCjEQro0EttUix6wHn84YXwsUBhZWWwKL8XfGTYMHS60Cth0EPzYZvusj4o2hERFnUNvds1xhO/nzjEzkw7IvMfPkSZn0IlH5jsDYXNe2z7Sq@BpGHPiciyqAMh6mNfFdGR1/ravESCR6h2cs5iza8VDylOr5QuvsI0Sxi8EtfgMKYhgQoQMYnpBFkJckezO0ReOEFuQ/I2jDZ3er36EBYt3h0xqR@WjdiowHYEWQmDEI/1MCT4WdcByWMLYdWXAjDpUsAtoHVvtAKyEyJp9aKhsqLLwBRvAzpybGcFVCBmCBeTLMdQW1BnfI5cQ7fCzkjDxVtqI2TYiwUmnMhgDh2PHRdGBmc6c1pNoCaL9C5fCU@Ec0VSZveXp1aYMuI44U9wFoQMY0uHvoBDDEcqaFY6cApgYlxJBp7n8BIjCNOoJ1g@fmfE@nlngrnUtg1UznR3zoFA9WB6hoLmzHRdYIOnOEnwOSiYTGTqpzAn6L0eclYkB437q4XL2KP3ph1zdlUT72Kg/NoTTnWX9VEJd0HogEGUiPe9eLJK4ZQzEiUqzniiUFZ@FyEhJZKhyRN90OthkngIjOb53O4mxKUhJqaZOJ30S2ISHJiRy2jsY1AVrmKH6gN2mtEJjGvyVdkApm9JgruEYYQJRigyRuguyBkwCEHLLJd7HZ1dAPdwmTTb46pIoJKoci4sy7B7YVk@IRCXaH1lXoTndskhRWY1rAEmp5rTJLFEwA@kBGUUIUBR/LkVA0ja43Ek1/DAqU1rcSzBRZEkOw@FX5gAEoSMCcKH2TUnbV9cuXs3EFw2ajXobCBNAdvsJaMabbBoKQOnhsQySSN@IfLEeT7BsZFIQn0x8SXHBsQm6Km1OjufDF0YceS/FCARkFWwsScHhPXb@al5Mu1dbWgbAzGRiKMOhCazOxGrAkz@fDTUbqJqfImqoPXGkarYeTE/gb7WeSkUG1T0k7mGh@JvzUcl0sIJxMDvqytJxLP6YYsOvTfvWr5IwF0w2Dk36gD6J/5iVsiI0r5MEAzaayOVA8HhwOGwZ7vHj2r@WOSRSse0K0sBltPVLQrexORikPfxwf2j3aNfbK@AYZmdytUAxcyVCjjVTmfSwJ4qOVmrbEZhLAA/aN8MGzMupxEFP5pJziwiKs27MLnMAnIeHn3tKklAEkJyUAngxt8VkYanAaFL6Oje8MokzAapFBQZZgnSMumABTBDB6KO8XqAz7Pp27fYeFeRGvvhiJk11TmAIFA5sIN8MkZeEcCCqE6fz4iUF6RQ08bNhoUrmjLA5yOUmq8iQ6J0pMt8dPhw/6hGYP11NYmSKN4EZCnd7cnQ560pqOCr0gD7A1eXpeQF4ihPE64rCdztLhF40bZsDXwAgLqO7DDJGgVV84aA@97VulGo1A17APkJwlW5MioPdb8sohE8cIrrosq7ahaliMVkFQatnLHC2OVpq5vPG8VcOTptdRdl9qJAaWMA5oFAbnQh6sSTMEReSJG@WO2j//zxNcQ9EiJBFZACzDyLyVSWZwmovUgmi3vKHmhojmXInxLHE5mYVJR4sDcgdz1SPiPp92fmJJFJ8qeahLRQ@u7ugfYgSOwvWdNKBikNqIvjzOT2cY@v60EfsR3LGThsC/Jw6TAoEMSmtdXcHTj2tRbSMRCrGsNtQuC/uHCjj2GuMd@S4ki5ouoq33DUbe8MuLRayCKRiEIESqH08mv9VAdyLer9/ODzfZhE1HwmE7ozdAEJInmIXOjqRkIpgElQkOzjs7KC4ZbhtdEeREiRPTustM/owoy7i@iVgcQxZWVl@pUofexco/hrZ36la0EI71rgiJDs4OmzxwdP95/sftacaPn8kj@XKReAcFBeB2QhecjphqN1iw9NrBaCi8HYcHF4AReYgoIS7BhNPRcYt4xJZI7Aml7DN1sTHztDO@4lr1bmDGOl13aXd6EnOPh4Uj8jKNo9C5URl@9Y43yO/Wc4mYy9iqLAKB9OOzIorcrrrmPpA4XywcRgWYqKqsvBIa5reKtyADLe3OA5@OIWiA5zWkHUrZEDygvteyNrYAkOnlatLHMwBF0YN8cNNymHPZhqo/RAQwBdWQnrRgyYfEBb/xm0k8i79ldVrcT7tZrRcooYJFsa/pB2o2@A6pSA2QpIkbziZc27zbtsDlwaIV0FEmPyFi1yeAznAouBIEmrpqjnB8QhboHrpcgriEZvpriaC1xKyWdyRbWQV0AtAzUNZFYJ19ykkT7pDqWJIwE8yenTukGkF/a9rm735S3fESALct8dqGq28bLZtFsgoDfvEm6499yYtxpqK1ll17Ns@emTVei9S9XDvhsEQN8lJ3RNerI1/KynX2dnPZ1GV48pk9HYn3OkMXuyC4LUWwf4dc@Ijj3MoEQjla2ltAomfqesWBCyMKuAN6SUAgMKZlroegriJYHQi@Ih9BzgW5EMbLGaEQpM88kQ@EeWJfbIlbwu4WJw1ucay6jgorA8ngPLo0TItKUsIhREUIFjDgFRiYMKhBIPxsc5CvyYSYSVod6PQ8904h5t06BohQu23hjakda7uzhReLhEOYEJOhx8OFFA/8J5gp0ZcVzK1z2@YAqZ/KMGQX5QF0MItDEQLorb4eEK6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV2@FioRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBBj0wbGACoJmXlFdnlFeEkUslylE9s5sxFax2AlqWNO@H6DM3Vxy93sResGybMaTwPQqHKRqYX25jtGly/08sxUC9BDdTYyRg6uZoCAR9zIoCrofF8f1VEPF81hZGck3LQE@BK7tweMtGvwJStphHoc9Op9Fp@4yq70uaJLb2FA3SDeYeUjTew3@nFAgOVTFrRQ4y/CkoDkjCjRp7Tkg5H3A4nb71rYs0S95owN@6rayZXSRLJKpyHicb4PdR7f2NiIV@L1eBpcO@DaRtcOulLg2iGXRC5MJ6OLcqTJhbENyoFhrfhlI4A8S7awD8xQeHlrjhN6o1LJttJ6Q/WfGj6T0BRAeUgt4QPgxJO1GjqTSbF@httGoEJE6r6Hfed51zXHPgk@BpmE@6PDS/SHl2tUUT2@mSKjmgt6q4FSbsKNNxuZZqt53uylmpfxNOZOVvUaqKjAPyeJkTxwnekYZMdGriIBe002spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsqAgPZm8U0qmdE7rRNyAPpVoNuNAUp86je7QJXiztJZMhoQCPPomKDqWlYjL5yUov5NsJVNxyJuMp2FmqMXjQBfa8/So0rgowTvRQ3MGpISBCbNsdFuDeDTtj@Fw/dwYD@duNEG48AeCPi7iL47M4MkinEiijPotzx@VKZcWGwLRm6cD@RrXD1FkG8/5BCNwTJvK0gGtYOo/lfojZ6Irn8igt8mRGTu@EVckCSZjiuGQqNpPTA@HsG4bztSLLnauXIPF0iH0eDgFZhmckktDrzLHgtEdOiy@eQ@gs3DLCRk/7p5JfA8uANDryvBDJoqCEe7XgIBD55pM4It0IowWhlRCgrOeYHsgXxi/kcPSqpSHZbAgc2A7riEBSSCHQIe46GigUA@2xg9o8e3a9OPH0qyKU5lpAEd8aDk60Zaz68iW1HgUyW8PMMuR0RMs4B99YI8ybwvX6ClbAm0UO@4QZgioDXJiLWytkR@hON64J09mkFVI4JwfjeQKJsi9Z6ynaVqhm@9XgjjsFUDsITQSKsY2aNlBlKRCZNJv5H2@MhUsEzw9fLDPl29ovscZHpfy2iOnNwXR1lfdjgx7kGb70J9M2xmZQIYg/9sT68hxJnyhATzrFoe43m6OppZOy05XV4ZuzNd1Oo5Fq1E3ZV2kn7qebul8HSyI3f3kCagbL46f1@RKJJGin45uLBuXQlcXy@l5EN32pC3fYIfK4x1T3MyLOG8Fh0@RzfgRBYyY@kdPoY2C8CKGB0MKt3H88BKGj/DYKYjr/kIGecNAP2GZEuJRVDx35weeq5lLDF@rBobpVErHZdcFtueqRuGnk35/KThLwScSsiZrEZyjYH4kdUlNjaKU54nwfOpSmiigAqUJj6muTVekdPyAjRxubj4Jz0EMDSvY3TwCiQV38GDSt1CuAr0JtQR@lNQAIX@MGzXEunH7j3VBDvauSbEw2MYSTy3ENmgAweSmoEgjbCrMX36v0hCyHX/b1ONs1XHTfGVnu8432lGtc7lGqfCNgc02gNiuV4Mzf@uSYUnxeJiMoBJukIOqSWcLrlU1PCni0Xq/QFmqgqeARjPTMlJzVtxvXcQVj8jQZ2KzObuT0T4D1QgPbW7eVQZGlY5ZraFXNYiJ@zJsZ84kkPgwFV877w6Bz7DUbJmU0D5Tu@9YPYlv1EGHYVzFwwbyz0mEh0n9M8OG6QbnSOkgL8@K/DVyBPUa3CtNWr@eIHJoNQQEw@ecXZykTy9YA6a8U9kbW@akxS7lidMe@oe17KvHW7kM6rr63BP8YzY1tnv00SeNTItDEEY6br6VeCvOglPSIDiDoITH2cGFh4Um5oQkAToMYWJ9VRmQmtE@DaAPMHgBVRYW5NcIUb8wLhZ16RugLCcMxNybj9LMSF7KfUufTAyb9zm@A7qe3Hyryi@mRsXv@PseFZahzSGQTE2MAxSr7Pnxg/2jIxl6rpeI7@MmUgWGo94dgoCyrtIBJaOVr7A7vTi7g3mSuHIgwFAD7aPt54dOXYVOD/oHlI68Y2C4CQhM4v5PF4Jpy40ycgnNJxAe@epOiEYhsISRhDoRsMpK/F/YXNXy8axAj08RJYHcibsVoK2ZlKe2@Ub2YKIhuRWS@MoqzBe1zQRxsU016Z/pG@HuNWhYJDRCDRoNJr0FLgeJRdZqVfkxBEiLCpg7QOqKIjUFHaavqUHT1yAYRBqC4GevvWMvGxmp3EptrgJF59v8c/C8/hG4CGEZtGesLHYzQeP92kDmOPDtSM65X5A6feUlkArb5A6RL3tT8uDMFjEdOuK1fFRr@SAYDDJkJbQahBUJWELMf0vB77MUT5wfdB7MRgGJJDsPia4hydnFBdGQbWqMaAgulfHGuAy0T2BMjx2ozWP/DYWodECj1T/LgmO2KYiBmrW8WYwxXIRXTq9Ip9KpGM3HpUPTPnFoyyl0tTOymkeJMMw9OrGu58RzsHRbShriwNNq67DzRp0@3VYkoJ0Xf0@fAmhN35eFQYjUlSN60PL@ipKXz7EsFeufkKWZFtxMenNLSqlcosT9TsdclxSIgEfTgueKZMCksD9rck5Wg1cecCkG5iNgXFx7WVT96hEotkR3/yiv//zP3@gB/a@3zhAmClz8DB1tmLqxpaT@2sbys6KHbqsblq/RTy1TJ8KQ6zaQXd2FKulW6FgNms4BSBJM/yPc1fBbHPom3kBqvKGbccz5pmTwXF3Iqn09G1hmd13aK0fCeFG0AwWKXY@IwIUg06BMxLp4IxgzvgsUUbGRjd2OVHBui1Fn5u0@nE6m/A6C662NaI7xd9PY9FNm8npHNRR@eP6GJnf1k2nPkcYng1BOLaxIu6g9bUNLIA74O9JtdK6uPq8gP4wePNclW0xtyhk9busVnj31xlKHtPAe99FAGN1Qgmvx@7okpv8OYehYTzXTotsH9kQfOnQU/0CGgsddpQjRzCtktvTOHGWQ4ZfvZeHhBuA4tW4qlcmu2d0ej9fnR02S8pfLq3PP5C6nx6o1AoUfqZX4KhpV2D9ke0urwnRljnRL0noR51pmvupsxLWk4bYq5cH3P@glkBs7OU5I3amluwvXDV18gUewjbBuRdqfNp6ZXQfEgTFTi7KqBVNHZMIglhmczlsUhCea6RY5gWGuImPwRosUulazAKc7wVOra/rUBzA0floUz@RGOonsrKNU1znD31rxYQiqKb@vntHersTqA5iTZHUtHebxtdPB0uIgLj7e0lHPTM@g22rCnqxEdNK1VoYvD4Fg2S@6jHdbt/ZMy/HYc7rfRKCBC1Tg99UdOkpLU7clWgyPum/gQcExi0WD6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2rT90@8n3/@aEcLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3NRC9M@niEduI84YpdhWb8vde1tcOFAPcuFtds4eZEuWUFb7Ut6Zg3HI50@fB8@eYOtaRNpg6xnMSp0G6wwzlEjgmLhexf57ScjeX1vswpnQNbPG2SkQa98QyYLKi@7UmZVpG/ZI51Ezmw1lU35oaU2OlonHYeW3g2/03KBkfjlTGr8amv1KPmwP4dkyY6q2vGX4Q1jhPo@9GZqJbZte4XZRZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdFzPMbCn46VWXdLO7KObSTYcB0Pa6S1hhzFflg@VbpGUluRzz6DfjRoT1/DwjFotn8lkfAEmsuOy5LlJk8qGeV@b/L5UMIUsSl6kxV02N@JcXQaRJXoKci0L0tYp9pS4XFZs0zYmc7x/IDftOI71ZVoKmCq@s@yAtirRad@bWuyauOO/x8IWSxceLnh0@usWLfhs4@uWQB9Umm9q9OiW0Ae1poSbniPckFr23rx8E9lguq0UfL8W14T4@V9rvSzpr4aockku3jjquITqdAxL549ZIXcTvLKcvRHeMtPwN2txc5dv6S624mNXmNJ4DsQye6ClDI2RQd4bpHy9h5Y6/MfaRDMHf@uiZ4bRVWb7RnddgrEJfMHG@9IeckRYmjg26FcTPGqIeoqFh1n90HUcONj1W0nkg5E@MLjpmJs45WLBAk/TcLVu4Vy9dFHhJ2i6kG1hE2R9l4BBdWLMveC5EuCTeRfadTq6fbntyuDv4hroB4z2dador0@x9tAZ2kNjyI@uh751gwP644Sb@rkJdcB6MMTTdOPx0in7KD0tx7I@hJ7IGjmjdJz@Spz28f1bfHnsS8HlL/v7j1sX7/QJ5x3oWDtqhsYU5iXPmThjQyLfuqQWLvTw@zoeGmxS/7wrSDfq@UCR4Pnzwr9VtxzozmQ8pkd7bE09ulFWiV6bvk1u6vOjKXQu03EH8ltn1JH9QNk/t0Jb4KtZTMecdIf43jrv2cbA6XSH5m1I@7YylGDJh3s/SHdFyphMeoDBsmUCed25jP2lFo1/jo@DdY3urx7xaS103CCvrFqhozfDpbF@0vX4aii6WAUXhCOjkb8/XqE38CtvpuZkATRylilc3uXbEuhYh7t/emKtZEWvaSzYsH@qYm0vJSEdBXLJyIDAo64rdvmcW2SIZbP8tg6haC0Jo8i5lC9Dbv/sD60OmpF1Wwhf6l9Lh5ZWTnL2cDrwrjNMvlzfAxENb@uXLeg4dWTJGuYs3fYf68isWQq@ZwnPNshcU@PGPZX8jZsqlE61JN0x4dGGBzTddO0ammWOPX5nUn/tVpx/lgl08av7hZw289XKtN8wPaPPt0DQdZuIOHJcPIkMMojUxZ10XEFHZs4FL864bGcATF2y2CJxkHad2LLymNDq5g/nTOmzp8ZAx7PWj80JHtZc0Suoy646XnQr7K9Pdc/8@hRqtq6zodEIvg3pRq0LoG8FvCf6wOw@WmqIEEmfwP5JT/5Y6v4YdL0tzoamhyeaQscNC1PY5Xgnxl7XBr1hRcqr6/ahvYzFAOJvYq5MvWpt3RnP8YW1ObluWlY3J7TK6j/XqY7rDoHdiMTZdDSeev5jNQ50Ziq6Cj06oXDvzATg0htgrWyoW5PVK9WRJVeQwvxJceFcJ41/blrOgH1eyjAQ2kAIQ@F8Rce5D9PzMzyQ49oreiKV/YHbnrjQIbm8Ym@gbQ18r8I2Jzev5kwmeDgneGJl@MyBbygoj/Eu3/uyEKTj1RR5fLusv3g7@pb5HXrec2fqdg10hiZPomqBX6qxF5w@xjc6HDTZchbV0rqOBcMLHNbKIdN17OlEcqf2jbNC4cZZoYIGryLdgCW@vv/kRTLaG@i09m1SaGASbeFae2DgSiczbRDE1vPR5dSBLvGAm2o6oqPCt@TZRXtSXWLXD5xV@s6zOUwgH6wwAfOfjh4YXdw2vLXsp84Tx3ZgNhoDoxwdGdzswNJBj9UZMdtjfLEe6NO7tZjnBHbNJMSlDX1sdKB9rYXrQ@YiDviBPtHXTEW0Nkj6X@i6ta@YVsdwX9OiX8S9TqVdRuiRMSPdYn2H4WNQmnS7XCTG9bilMbK0Y@ONHcfmd@K2GXioT27mKjAV0O3DN8plPIi/tC6wUj9brurhKT8lYvS4XYx1dXWNjmPx@w1nkmyTnwnQXdPwlMdoZoHCCjkmgfTl3chDijfykIVqBJLsqe7RJv1qVWMBUp19iSNAQ93tOrgT5jtuOJ0TsY1wC5sOz/bzgwMdIPwMOJbenfr2Sm9Dyxp1RnRbqzBEWvPI6OBbQR0yKDLRZ9cbk68M@dYUIie6QhsEAbvCQV1giWegjSRvn7aW9KhlqppjuhGnXrtdTod1JNs0um91XDVziF6LtemleKiz8pSca9aqI8OIVpEVnV62XzmSlo@ugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xuWt4OLL2s2A@ZjgzcZF7ehVkrujrekCrrrN5PD5mra0i@uUHgJaHpQS4fSrtrJU8ED/@H9z9WYBJuF3KB9RNgXbfv4APyU9f2Hx/SA5853qRvzg4Bb3wLYB07wWrlIQs8@MhA19a6SkDr2VOLrz4MIueuRj1SxyQyBi1JFrHriSEZ9qlEtuhm12vk8Je@lF00IDwxepJvigF3GqTHwftfYTL/uWIDNcob8bCnqnDCzgo5//jnKuKeBZwB5C1nIo09eipj79nB48NjeeypK@en3SG@HXFNjluy7aCVMpElqde6G9nv5MfReqY3Ue4/V6W9xwcyJlhDb76jIcEDd@aWHmvXPQNDsoq@VgvCWGOyWkB8dPzkcWrxiiZL7A1dZ2Qko9F7z5@n8U2Tj5@vjI7mfgijo@/M1mY/2FfV5Iru@8Km3cF13HNFSesgHRugjUJnfMRNw9wqXHWdsdE7no@NT2DyRA7ufWDxhbWVfKqfmgMchay8llA0UFlZLuSSkZPZoGwbbvhc154n5hi5ZZceCn@sPY6CkkNWcbOrpYebdvyvSjEs459E@HKZ1Mz13ho1Zazo3t8XMVVV19H5ud6HdmX5tY21nGDV/rDlnH7AVrLhKy9SGCRNoFdJ5q3nyIvSCFi3gjdcnvcDwdlZewzmJgBhcGHlgD8z7LluS7SXdZN4UYHceKjtxiSfGx@wIRWe8DlFe@kr9/jCI/Us0SVn8paCj91Ilr29@we3ZTjyaXlzqo@evmDPdA/toNycMIqx8QEYLySj1xKuW6ERvrXbqT0XQGk3whuMV4/nCnuuuz3Hns9u34Sjd1Bxaif7xiEs9FEiwzJn5qq5qsvXtZ6tPmZ0W9n8JQ5nviQHR@3j@IDef/ufqWomQ9aP8KlmuPeWlgkGOEugS5@jSb1o1PFByBq6KLfIEJBcqY0@NmZ4HIWvBq9S6lfOb4Ub5r5icv10clNc6Ya43A3lXYvDQJaVM@oNAPM3xLG8HEY/dqyzoSPv6a7hrTh/vBKhmypSvqEi5Qh39g2208ai714v4uOrC/5jZW89NiZubjx0OmZuZR12@2jnkj1Be@3X4/3jFLpLx1sGjv/KB/evLu9saqws6In@dnUEcZqTlVHABI3hlF6JuB69vEHaAZnXsAcmN/HI7juTffLdoJiFbzyvPotgjh9Mx@sxBt6IX8W4ys6XEn4KOrNz5rH7@GrcQkxfofvj@bjV4etkWhYuDKKl00fHu0HvOnyuaJESF1h89mwpGF8enRw@j4S5xmy2TumVZut0yJUxi1KfHueWit2uvzxdQaz17xuBuAH8OHyulYM4s/v4@XWWgOrbcDKygpiPdXuxYrrUYD1nQm8arox8Np/RMcqVLT3kp9hWxbndFcFLij1MyKYJZXtKu43mmNrtdb3y2PiM9h5ADGITLpZwoL7hJWOWGwYYUpa1A9U5WQg/S@g@Hw9Ne7YyarQuD50iTbz2Vg@DXfbccs7Y49Cq0Dr2oK0Grp8a9jrmtOplRamcvVkKy14Rqda1C/@Aiv9Y1yT31wlqV3gGHoi4iZtg/qOu8jDwfKIlb03/8fMg@e1p9ywH1@975nR0e2ICm0rdntC9gf1dBWjengy/N3IydFz79qRBd6pU7hsfiMTGB6cczbvOB@DQ6fdvT7TvObcnejK1JibqLKuTPnWmFloQWBW37w5Whte3682mXJHXRaJBd2/oJtfH47lIZ@qBDmSGzDPMKL02J0uBQZ@JhqF9ecOWbSd5Be7HDvsaWpJfQYq3H9hGHz9cl255w2aKW/z0RvDCue5Q73ievXWQvzUH5PmQQWeboxvTLkz@HbiOzX3JddPjwvzfipIe6ZZ5K0MLDjxoNx994G/lA1OPflTCS/s2ubgVC247wJODL38kEja0fXL5M2tRQwhoej2xiaaHN8noAaS9uGAbvqEBiBAD0wW@aQW0UGraUwNtI/CPL01qm1BMrabmy2wHv2tWYWqGysTPNZa5IcigsAbbPPfNBlQq6iXbqDGxIjLfcENo153bJgfAaFUZKsWkE5VtTiBmMzA6wOgzO@yC0Vqp1EXjteCTlaj5lapvlgFw2jx/dvBs//nx7vGL541M69I32xDUwrahtMA4zJ1sT4TK@3QDHYx/qYDMhVhQHH0CCNdYvaBeDD8rtly12lLVFpUSdzDP5rltKwpZrlCkS8BPEnlpFIuSBARx2EGNqYF8oyUVbkSCbGFAG3HQIpUJjVZhmVUFj3XQJzZtP/7qV/goFr/UWMFvNWLBvnF56L4Dx@n5JXoGu/0KSny4e/D4xdE@CxBc9JozszcZ1sp5/u0Bbk0H2qlv0lHeGov7WeLQVrVa/GEcCBOX46xCtkbI7j90dEgWUAetlPi5t1hik@ADBeNhoyj/@RvKZVzGt1KSkDYeIBWHYqHPU0fZ2Nhgx9BJ2IOjg0/2jxjiv/@AgpFECIIdo6GDP/txj385JzBEFnyl0h2R8E@GnISosZPAAsjCSAnSnMbueP23KulLNWQKJPxETviNL0GgLyhBvz0jM6ZX7EsmyeQb/7amb/4zKIi6UPC1DdwARVOersdOTc9EQySIQx8tay53djwzSQZtZbaLH@LEz33q9BknQH1qT7j1Ot@GVQx6mhzynDTbJGT5R5/ESML49gZ09o4BeiHzbBNmpkmFvYaeiJuMFW6oRpLq8WtZAtAVckmoS0QSXjPF6SlNV3n/a/9EGVQZuCfg/o7vnmXug@9XfF8f3L/K3S8V7GjXTXcucIkihBZ//RpwREL6I@0j3x@1uXGgBeHQwmjAWJk5gmY6Japjcl4Cv0vAjxdwEo1PoNGgu0GL@UaBeHmG20qgyeGKomCXwrUKmSZYY8bPR18xPVzIF3KqAkhKpwFA@lbIAA0/cIDJZAWGiXBqjmuvQP/d3t5mIi5YGrVClbessmm/zIqvQkQ3Ia0AExog12CQB7IsckBc3c8Gs09KTWJW5F5xNY6Mq@fAtETxOH2h3/YJIbIEEIvTyMCPT8zwU7UTEON9E9od/Lhr5DtSmz4gSYU5iVxJUfDN6Tx1JtB9YJAuvhTHzeng@wF8CkTDsB7/gDNZrsb@KF8fWQsrEMEHq/yxJiMP4KCymauzabRtxU8RxHMEURFXdd/GS9acNO2Wwvsmg276wxWd2Qb3LyuDNX2W13v3utHgxFWTv0gsdu@57eDK7EOoDEtoipZV1EJyUaVcbmWV/Br5xUB10DLZBRQHbApYRtcwXztjb3dv/@Djw2fPrxnGpZTxq8mA79e3U01JTjdaoSMerdZyk9x/qDx/cv9h0BALpAsRbgyM36@JelNNFhsuCHLxAt/Vqq3C8Grt1mP8KTfxcRXfrHYTapTpGh5q5kuUSy/RSA/pVdirhWulVdTK529CaQFPiYDe43YMrqGaSJ5fNlqgFtmx@PWesGIgvIzJWzgIwNX0tjYV7OzXK4cVCz@tfowfrPSiYzG7eiyKm1m0u4hmVCbOycIypR8QiYjUNygGWKQgK0HStaPvkAvpC/upGv/0OzfYGDVHF0G4kLmJ4hFQx8FX5JGLLKw/@4aPh6CyWGZHCMwAcgPIgZ3W0PYxN@GXSAr@Z4x4wQn/u/KzykymE7OJJHI7gpVmN9lSDuAlBRjQKN09m4Lq9MwZ889a0MmoB0bgOnKA/T6Y8pVUg308HUG6Pj2ODNqlBs4tQWagZDxElctSwCV8U8qzFBqrhvIaaFDZr7g86uUTs6Q8NGY9cwC8PZFMA0e7o6otFppbxkqTeWU7LlKbLVrhxqH4EVqniJL9S9ncni0Q0Bu6bNo9Y5aIn8WTlRaUj@Hxs09P40lxVV8i29@@MezeVSPgIfpF9WZOok/80RlY2F7FLcrl61wCwq4C5sYog2/qlcvy0BPoG6k1lNyfT9zH4AQxItEf6WOWmNrckKfMyJtoJuw0WTiU6txIsM1SKVKo4EERMqOcfXLx@Tuh23OWUGr4GV0I9ewePt6aY9ZQZbkFbiokyTbxW5d7IHGhadukAEowZKkQ2Bp2IVAzACM@SGTewSEPxkNaeJA51BXR9Ok/2sxzkCZUa1a/yyLfLl2WHMVyueI36DJXLDPofdfZoawA2Gt8LpDrgbq@jS@gGai/shBbMPLrHC9G5cY4Io9842CATixi2DuwGcYA1sLsdnfo4i@xb8NYAfmgUnlx/LBdSioiC42MDVyzh5vN/PMYoYrnf9AMhqmylDRe5RrdR5gNzbm2uRUztCr6kAaMeIWlxqJk8E1iB8qyt@ibqnpjr/cz@q0AKXM4AfgvY7cDcGiCN1i0WRG3mtn/7GcxFDYSm6p60nZPU/F8pgo3tZpneXZnsylJm41M7d6mDlrU5M2sCTq5spV7cGoM@72DgdIURZZlOUXZOj8/jz/cema@zLOC1DO1wpvZ/DJbyL6ZXWbV0puTsVpoyG9mLbFUS5@02LNnn71rv0uKs9P5G7GZ0GJ7hxeimkOVP1Yps/OdQjZ2Ugb1E8pl7IS9heukz/Cf3G97EbeO7k4fVNi4yGLNJlBcFYuiojTiLfgndf8VXFzxb9TlurzTevcu2dD1yWzOTNMce70e/JwhSJBa8jkDffkucHqeQWFNepIGhddo1r@@npBnbLZrDAbTfb2u4Xv68r12dW5OH06efP5pcL3A6@1RJNtb/@PaqVRCkhor1ikqbT0fw890/9lPNi7T58/a23/2zZFibODjEB/fuXyC7udq/s7Gxp3793O5tKZp3P3s82e/uLu7m3uQzj9r5HdyUmZj@0//ZGND07Y1ZaPleWor3jg5@UzUMjlR/rMfxdvPnn3d8@rZ//Mb7@oq3opwO2VF4BNwZZkKTryX4KeijPWhV@xtDHq5GpvTXzsWhJ9vMLW@U/wv3zt8E5vE6pryqQvPSexNrFCKcSc4wJcNfKexemwbkxUuY3OlVquBs/hf/i3kr38McDBmvg23ej6AVZjH6lKNslzE6gVwqJoG5f7f3/hGBEPOJmokxgXXPdaAS8wVNXGnBdcWXdsCGm@VMooSpLMnw4nhMLV0V72LHhM88LAN/AqGMWnG1FKOscN7jB01UqlUS25LcMkvaZFIUVWtqap3gR1Id7ZqNWmLcfO02Wz@LprYT9KS1sCBGdO4@@k/xBVbFVj9ucEdCbHCxr1XD@p1qFO2nt2qp@jyBxKNqWJJdJx7IkuzV3FQQRqtV48Zt6ldFzMlTUyn0/fa5J8hraRZ2JPw4vdYLAzBIcuuhi1lgSR@aOzLp4vt4/Xn/9uff//Pv0d/36fff0DrtnbP7CtbkOgUhkQdrnuVSrdeF@uueN5Efx36UaZSqpSU9mUzsQUcqHXE1MxHF/F8Nv4cuT9dzSSMKUpPxdb94tFfjy2C6zykHg3zI3hiCoCnTykWW6YauUOqMXYlHUyt/nsAUuO03pJQIKpJDbWQb0k8Vz24yqxxD5pJ1IplsVXX8tohu9ee8YsNNz3mxEAzLAR09PGtL@pWD2MWvno0KFYPstUXab5suhBfIdZoKC2DJoQgjN3bqGyUKoWKprTr6y/omlEvJTUM45kXO42FF6dsbEHQWNg1r4YFTRF6WNCD2ZdJB421YrFbu3IxaqVsQRWrvktrM7EKPUTLStqgLWZUMRxtuL4P1wb80T9coRfvGxTiB1OS69cGq6hbWlbJ3ynsazi/3nJFkRdgnmDdTqfzttsBqUPXO3pXVyf6VJ/pc33SmXZmnUl32oVhwzNAX@P/btbJOyUn8MpSLJtXN2N3YdbBxNlyNlvMZQuFbKGcLeazxWK2mNFK@axWzhZy2bKWLUCIli0WtBKElLJFNVvCqSBbKmulXLaYFWLvGhvsiPOyFksFVzN16/VCltu@kxwO/iTJmcWE2D/AVVc1lW3BLJeBG4h25ATNG/9UVWAxENfOW@@2Gu@2YJjXU9vEYlt1yccSHnL7XislXV42wF2t@v/b9dBZpYu7oHKty1Rq@2UdZJiX9UYKQL70QcoSI6Byu97appiwML80P3q7BVKQlNpubNecPfrJNMykeM6JF5x7LQC8vYTsvXspGVz3AEB9E0Z1MpXalKQNnGEb/owDiVv1VFArxCEBMsf5@c/5A3UReMHl9mX9srF9ebm9Df/bdL/0nxB6uX3tnx6La02aRXwLGVSzodSbStNnOS3wy0odQ2SlCY46PCFdI6uVWg10wCW3/tv8l9OLexiCKLdkwFqIbbGtGFpszca2hNir91/8L/hrvv/i91HqZPBnVITYOTIHZQt11jJXXeHG7Cc2e8IvG9z4C7wYggFP6hho85uN21qK8kpmFb5zkFBLhaSM03jb6bfRCIzMXkHSJZaKfJOJWqkgtlPqXGOxbbFQJKb5C9eueDz@j15p5WKcL/egFZNXnuc9iWC5wBMSV7WMKqkXdf6hDv5NpV9Ydf2jX1h3CbGLMjMqQJ8E44QRYtCPYooiSTDt1bdH@JoLbrhIqNue1j6TXuxKuBijT2g7rcsXGmoH@7Vyuc73ijaf0ajZerAFdxX@9zegGqzZh7TNfq07AjG62c/mtSZ@1SEmdd7g3@O3@MeOu/h39Ab/2PFb/Dua4B970sG/4zf4t9vBv@MR/t1/g39P3uLfiwH@Nb@SzapVcfOcKJNSy@rl5kwkClVhlqo3vzJx5xX6RJmo7WigPPrrVYlsrpyMNb9izLrGeFLxFxbxpSOjO6nqtXK1U9P8pP6JaYyRTS/4Bry/jljRWBJXPLPlvONKeLwPbhCQypZVx43/9Lvf/Ga8VotLcfq6VA7CpA4m6lAi8ELOHMcEv9oL@EF7e168ei/@lQatJeTLrQZGtiBCiNXYprqpZqxMN6N21A44TJZxWWaYGao9lXSujMEy88ycZUaO2gOXAX8ZcJmZPssMWMbO2JAMYsE1aWcm6OrDYwB/fQDkwp@JJ8c7aqbLoCALZU/6kK7axpyZi3ZTaLA4E18ZoDTLqpyRC2YLv/3VEF@9aipbLa1cYjL2a7ndeNWMt8SmiN@D0Mo51pkbG81XIsgYGZH3fwxhMc8DTbwaU5pNhRMeyEUteXnZbu8/fdBuKzgTNp84h4v/w8NR1Hvj/@jQeXLojBz4Pzw8hNFr1FP3UjBH3LtXgznDf@zE6tWdZoVmnmD2iSnbO816VkJ3IQUTioZhqS95LSDCs77RFOJnoAmdgRJVTYAqdVY9rVbPyPEp94KjjW4MDP/PfIf/JAjVUBE7g@uUwJIPnWefNkMXdyifnkHQpwwUyPAfNNWo97/Cv/nf1v@TFyzJEo1WMnF@uZ2gK4l/yeT55fmlf68nEwnfk9iGPwwAP2Y5v6yjkxKdg6uRSLaSl5c8DO6J5DYHWIdituuUd5EOZqZYWCQVy2@J/7pPKNq/mvEqCPB8kSCfoXEUE6tMXxwQajZnmUwS@Jz/qRvc7tYv6BRGskrfOd3sNNTWn/6IPme0k6RE@Vy1qm4x7tFyWrWaC3zFUrVaCjybiUT5@lXP7KgFUKRyuWSyWgXPTgA2A17I22DvUqzGmnBv3b3LCylpFxcBzGyukMrgwaxqNSgpD8Uant71mf75wSF9CQhYTT6Gn@DirCSRoe@I4UQQFyvi3buJnoGvJ/R2dpN372rlzMVFGDIeQ5C6FNRu90y33cbw7MWF2BbpQE85D/5M6eJCzZRTajzpuImn@JFTKCohqeyOVqdSy8DktVwRon0E8tvbhVy9XshBSKEUT@LhAM7iAd@4GK@KsXOqg1oqcg4oVjE4etAJxrKHc@35ZYwalOXyyQQw0iSIoZcx/HOR5/K5Lp9PAmUuRZ5SLZd50iTLFRKlVNn/q20kWR3kLP6HwmI2ldsqbt0DsRv/vNmqC3ly9dyoqZe1c6OC2wOX1a7/xXq0pmPcvZstA4lKmWpTaLcf7B7vtts1mMtQVoMbBhJ3F9DIkBuvVO9Ru6qlPIMG5IFSHKYEVgIqK9pWXi0hVQSzj9axgAYC1/M22Iag0RNvQpmTagMCQYWC0npwsR7rsAFebIBqJzOZRRezGI@ne7cbJnL45ceGXspLmmkQYoSX4A@7LO@TMGs/e7y7t3@c1rYlFtMe7u6ltecv7sdU9OYXforOov9of/fB4QvI8Ozx/u7z/Y8OPtl/8QzCPXa2uAIu798Xz6hrhf@MfSq8dt/qhqEbU8Non02nZ2/Ya9Nsm9B61hQq5Qxc5hltqMtYX9SrCr@u6emvX@vumC72/offfv/D/@7973z3/e98@/3vfP@nX3z/2/D7Mfy@y5/f/TflPN5/@sU/@933v/07EPgf4PdH8PvJT7/4jW/wH/n/GH7/KRL2x/4vko7/BID1Kz/94ns/@ukXv/oD@P1L//eD679f@8nq3/e/tf6H@b73uzen@e6/hd/vcVhB2u/@Ng/D57X0v83T/eoP3v@Lf8f//9T/Q@fvvP8Xf4w33/NPf/Cn/@n9N/@9ppX@9F@//9b33n/rm@@/9Z333/rH2vvf@NdqJnr73fff/4O/@sPf@6s//B/p/8d0/70P@X//g3/6F//rX/zvf/GH/u8n8Pt34PrJX/x7GCp/@wc/xP/v/cHf/tEP8f9//ld/@we//re/8j@R4ze54//5l/@G3//61/7j3/zWd/7qJ9/4m1//yd/85h/81f/xq//Xb/zHv/7vf/@v/8k3MfA3f/JXf/Qrf/nNb//lt/75X37zizX3b994/@IDwr/4Bwj5cDw/BM6H1OvLhnzxc@Hz96HGohToJ9C7f/n9b/wSdPB/wdj7b/8YXzyF35r/H2sqpfkx9/1/wKFdrzPGZMAFv19//@3vIon@ByAR/If0@k7oWYrhnu8sPEDW31qR6Zd/@sU//xH5YkalTvtNOFmXtFJqCxSarXLZn7D9rSjI8kvL0EIAfknfQQ61FPcd5G3vf/iN9z/6x@9/@Jvvf/grOFtLuXJ6Ny2pt@zjQcL8B6TDhIUPSYcJP4Py2yla1pNSn4Fv47N8KWvbdvWzzz4T2hcKvuF874J9Bn/ss@BiPArfgPajgjgMx1eiGYQ3Xr1q4eZvJExROXBF408/Cs/mQ0mSdie1o6gajzIulE2ei1UhIFvKNiOoK/3@VgX@GNwqla3ztLTTBKGPsl4KRlAl1Ye6oTBVT2e3sjokVHI8HavY9zK5VHFL10EFTiHcFMk8W4EMls@yWcovcsZm/qr3DBPNtsg5o2VwvhYOdwFv9F9krMSyjNn8vyqwFK2O8z2a1MJJDj@fXwR3CnkoJjULt99IKGRcKtviIbSzTuXmygxrMJulZqBtgwNKSEHUfZD7a7UUZqxxFMHLK1MvMUIllapBvTE3z5NulxDE7D5BgZy11BFrb9VmPGMK4dUDcqQEDDoSVU1MlWoPoMDa7AFDWAicwL56VauXarM6gnvHqZOape4TTgislprV34G/RjAhnxB78A5QKdVSqXoJC8RK8uZJt3kj5alyVPcUS/ltAE98QWLnHmN3RLUk8m2VDSQYT4331CI1JoTkEN9MbfnVof/ASb8tIvgGFeWXwnj8DsnEO1xMxgQAV5JkWWbwwxMLO@weRM84qBQVC48Uh5CiHkE9IAxguBCVElLUvinyQPmx2taXvhAYVmZzc1OI1cWseCgT6RSFuScVelsED1CiHlNhYqEsYrBBr84EuED@KpW/GcetyDjjgNmdFP/du7fF7kA16bkIE5iUyjo5J8ahbKdSogbw605KeAn6jwD9lABdCPKsRlufKSGdZkyuxTCOHR4e@khQwMuakIJurmVV9OMG3HQ6jUEOWU7L6bT/lOlJAbLvkCnWf8qbSNwz15wYTNNyVVDTqgyDWFSnUkHXxsB3795Bq9CJtMoBaLnMP5ym5UoUCQHcwJRlzYN3rLRcWeBLAEwt5BhL0HIyXEmGLxMloCMlBf4mA0cjuBJxrVSKU0qgv5zYCk4rFlTkAPytLXrfmOWLS17AJurFZUG@@ByrY82CiyurpXwyiNw7ZHuHT57sPz0et1pMwK/NTidGe@w6XcPzEhi3@/QBf@lFKxeSsUYDqXJc0ZAjCfuVDHbU1MGDo4PnFcap5LdZgupRpa1rny5lVYiNx59ux/zDXSJ@MtQRn@O9siBFQisDt0zG6kKsa6AKhGcSUDWvsqrwxBvcd2YskUmLYlotoAqaxB1YwOMXnSlDg9bc@hUMQnwVRt7eJgoI9XMp2NpBX50daRTMsuUid6jFAobzs5JME@rP948ByvEhU7WMLNQ/YzMZsZAuhbpVswx7MBlu4qFDsZkRIxXdbGTS@Kdls3BXc4W0mi@2NjascwkLalLTn@Pp0UvwnktYt6/CxYSvCuyrEAQXlIFHQpm/bH5wWPUPRaI9yQQ/GSmqeRisSQGX/jk4YRy9qjBGlrfOhNjG559PWL2@//SBdPBQiAHPGbLgXKBk9uShTG3fm7oGxQ4Y65mfmPiBWLlnemNLn8MABGrELi8v@wDp4CHT6hp5eY4e3i@7FNIB9@VMF2J2pVJ7p@aKwtFupfIuq2kCBAhbCh483IBeQec3thT@V/WgkGy2pAC/U0URHtlsVqA@LVQMgdEZnXeZWk3iHTObU@mIjoDfHNJntcWmu592dmeRNpvhaTEGIthg4rJMEFfkcb6vIJAPiIanEukL91V/iGfu3s3imks2lwkXV6jG7BLaZjObyyLF8a2vVixX9LeVRFFsxQTLmLBeDdyxJtz4@qGmxkSGPmQ92VJGiDViDeH/z5e/a7Y9rmcz6rYyBqcOzty2ooOzA878ttIBpwnO8rZignNaz6qZbWVaF5iwzc1QM7RyVRMnxgyt3vMwse4ZVl/GF8FqIhWgidv@Zx3qQcZ6r9ZzulM8g1PtyaZtGy7apOAZcjmx6thoILUW7FUB10qeC4PaGVnOEIzaQEabW66tW0JP7ji9uexN5ha@UmU5bi0Okm48iFhAN0AEwvW9nWw2V2mwljx2xjuCli@mGmoG5i78qaW0lt4wdorFSk/uWobu7uQr@VK6h29r@VuJO/lMZSB/9uTxo8lkfGTQK1w7uTJkQCuVaE9up1TJ51uNhiimGlRMq5FpyZynSRsbwAgMvSfBEzcaPUkrtSBzz3RrtXh8J6tqklrJZkqXwoJwSHOsYV3ArCmsWRrpfu6zjYrt2MChKmk9bZ4TFSr9fv9y6zy18Aj6ucR9QJ9LSU93zkNvVYqkq7BpWjIXkRCi94Hc5/4eakXU8iWx2qgu/MWCWG1dCvdGRs/U8c2tZub8eq4CcHIONQYFNZlwWXEdZ1LpGH3HNRYJs2ohSMgRup4gJ16GxTUzWOL59eIKkUSz8@tQcnnxMswVoCVcXgLdObGB7L6N8TqdcG6o5VxrH/gWdJ/twPw4Jou9fCnEto4@ydbr0NTnuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1mKTKuQLoexk1U8jkNQ2g5MqlcvES@rWivIvR10XZ3nnQ3yv0fZWEXuEGghstlnz31LTOS1mJ45FIVi8vY@@E2J2jTzSYVddeCZi@P9Gkei2bL4Mriy4tCwgzQdMkLStlVUnN4v8tDg3/Pzy9Bv8a3iFXVhOO0WrYU5hrQWiw2WO0PjRx2LGD358bsPtGd02KvaFOx8/3XMfz/h5p7uv2CY96YHJT3WHUIx0/wumNzMlwTYoX4xEaHDPcfzAI@6MOIIjskCe4DzfXcpxVCYrsxbM1tXwSfhwDiMG/jgHJjw4@enQceR7v7@49Egrs/uHTB1ceeT9Rnj3ef3gceos8NsiaD0H84v7jx1e9/iN3@OKoP3Vc/AkPD1/kFrcwCN9uFnJwLScKgwmIf0MviagghoAOmC8GDlXAd2Lugl5@13fmCwtnBp2f8le3TS98R4O/xV8RjoP3uXWGnLZjsC63K4cLBWTz1Vci1GJZEMbMds5YMcN6jmXpLnP6/Q0IHOr4bqqBorFlYU/Eos8c1@qdmT1jQ3iCr8GWQcPoExLCIwAymnbJZAlIQGhBHGY1m@HWW8eaGmw6ZmsD4YFB6HTNwRDm4DMnSCB0dJ3B78tekN@IXpObAya8DAq7FmNdTy6AOlnKi@KeKD7SJ3rVNYovM5XKM1f3Bsb@DPoqewFjR3fn6VI6K07Eh0xux15uaQPcx7GcMSoy3rgBQj5oYjvNv/6tH//dn/z6oAYsppnZy@RxDWp758njnDPXKzaXAJXqO5avAJcDKZiRoOsLwzLpSlq5lC@Vs1opXSqXcnm1kM@nVS0NemmxDEpFRi2phVK@rKZLuTIIJLkyxOZBk@GitBLIzspWBcDaXWvaM7ZJ3ZKHoFfxXVf2NqEnWUwP/VMmGpBHFFAVntAr/1tmDeZSpmZYtsgAos66LPbw4V7m4UNRvI8ePLWylxHFHnrypUymeF8UDYrZK6FwJTo8TwlNtIoT7slk7gO1pxwAft1EFIfo2S/gYqIomujZ2334EMvpo0fD/JDshMdwjxV4ipDMRg9I@ATgTQgNku3ycnKE6D56sEiMechj9iBOFD8K0MGYI56MA3gU1HR3VxQPuGd3F2P2qNp5jujX0LNLlyi64IFRIIoDcAxcGH@i2AEnjgVR7IKrO9chbAQu/ACGPdFFcc7JgwQSxRml1rsnotgOwrGYT3xs8kjdCnlUXut75CnjnyhqAdKYLBt6sqKYCz05qNujR5/ow0nPGPBr7vJnF2r66FFWN2fT/Yedjz7qDAYdd767/9ERRu3tPQLBZD51O4OOn7HThsuBXHuPNP1kNL96Qa0P2u2Kbq2M@lq7ndPtK1HtedtADCHXG8DMvwZY0Ki9B1F7j9r39FW75gSwjWxgBM8OXvdH8Lyvd3hUcFEUPWedjljF7q8ozYSAqgNuf@NwPAG2aqdHetd1quif1VgmjdLLvFHItKoUwUagAmSqlxjfT@BdxxWo5Pm8MatlWrVZreifd@snxOZMy5tiemO0o5bzlQ19R9VyqVkFrY44/TiLS@oOS6h3t96yxNPkjgbqgNjc2ZHEhtra0dRSpVB8uTUVxWQF7zvZYuVtIhPPMIa3ZKPY2inmIzmKxZSuaJViEYQyoMkE5vYOrvO0E4kzQz9JJhFbWmCAKlBd2ZzqaVb7iVl6VuN4sXmyOqupVW74nWWuAevhV0am3YnjcpADADfbyVTwqEVCVMslERBQlEQyGTI90PeFxaHbT79@fHJ8/BlJf3V/7eOZayD3qvrejx7tyQeHgQ@/DyI/RKHUceU95FpLMVw6DYKOQR2RH8F8CqpdEIZvd7qOJe/TMUWQbIOIwESZ7Nvqlo8fLcF5PnTOeMloHKNKBl/trsHw8ylmj@m1Orj0HksQVkxPntFM3q7Xa@3aiOxHQBWDXF9j9G2RBZgDj@Memuyg7Of4xqMf0a5lLqud2iw2AzjtGpPUVyOn90pLdas9/GrK/dp9zFxtw7NTNWqG6zquCIq1WO3v2LWp7el945nhojGag8NNkCvwNchEnxnJTdbcx9R7qLRcSnWX2QvMnk5HCV2qd5LLQbjYFwYgcRJfDyp9Tm/mtmuieFnt11jiJSR9A353kyV68v3kTq4KdLrP2kkIyrzqv@ozjRVyVVI6EggLhhLRB@uts2St/jV4cNgnlQpg4zf0CUDFwgCw2aMISD02L6vdmsUSEpuxJBEpVx3UGpj9Am/bkii2JKlx0RLqkvSpUIfxWp3H9Jo37dAHt1imo2qZQnUGYWoxVx1C8@ovZ1W3Np66RtUCr78cyF9C1qtAVKAdgHl7kXj/S99Ibkv5Gg@rEqgLFALacrs2q9powhc6Ri1bg4hUI5dJgzoPt2Ia5nytkFYL6Ww6l5aKGAoTfjqfhkBQd0DcSFgJkTExnZllZDWtGmo6kXll9l4l0ycJkGCIaCyZnjj79nTEIASaCvsmeeEJ5ElpWxaoYT2H6dsSdVZgGVWsGFB9yMZmeoigjgzdohzJpMSyWwlrM4FpNo@n4/1Gq1LZn42/DlEJ6c1OIVXMpN4mk9XERrLmGW@EelWoI3uhWo83oOf6K6XMm44a0MrgUotapdHoYBWLmXQ2k4Xame2LwbZYF1vpzEZBhSa6ZMQ2GOcb0cVDlHgWYeM2iuGWAU2nlrWqINNKXrakSWUlv5XP8NVEnlMY@@wNKckSTTF44T4Rjxe1eDwZr@JuyIbor2YDTyN@FgfuGr@r7oggjIkVsaxhggVrpHeqMwF2II5dCigjshxouefC5fnldl34ivAc35Td1l7iX/Hlk91D/PsKBJXBW3r55MXhi8OHAlPoZCvInNWNqlxtV8EjyfV7QqzCGHDSpm8NTNlg7MuemU1t11/yZxPf1wC4Apnlb7AWnWUzTFTh2CdoaWKHxaEOujtqaFq21dCKMPcBNw2SappaBSzaMXwjRK5DY8zOAb/tVB1f0vwam8/1lBTo/Xcr9UFqM6PNY6dtsVDO8pcN62rmhG3Ei1sMxBmJxU5PNuqFrVT8WSWbij@IZ3Ox00Rzs47n/8tbWyltHpe2Urizq/S2Uv1S6k52K/4iVSkN0hU1hXcN7pU4kzZi99rpe8myJ1CDsNiVZYjd2u7gaDc4ALi7Vy9pc//V0tjLtlgq@gg2N4FgWurlcu46TL0vcbm9KeDLBPHYeZzF4pfwJ8Tu0eurGn99lcXCF1hxQ9zfJsrmCiwZKyd9X7Ec8xLhHs1X4vdicdwKqXjeuxh1qODtwK@90qAvx2wnCAC9DtfcYK7N53FrIKa8Gnufa6Xsk4ND@4H70BBizY2LDQd3b9jitOM7@@OvMzYG8sZZsxab1XL@wXy1XpfUbQ0N9hVZBaaTvlqQMhd1PmDqFFHQIOb9L/0gN9sG3YdpGRX8mpZPafW6uqVBxcbvv/h9NL10vv/J7mMWx@X9v/uTH2nFv/uTf0Xn9@KXtOSvZYsxSIlOtVCMnZ@Pz88v4eJx@Vgrdu3YQgvoo6h6ubglQ22Ukg6OthLjdAQBqqgmY54U8w9pFvJSIqEqWnIrW8okIebCN62W0DIl8AZbYRQkFvJiMrZ/ZOY19d72DtRsJ5vTqhvQlmr4KjIL/7YNr4xa5JNXF4yBp1vvDQamRi5FYZV30vY7Jm2zd7gL9U7aYK9qdTx2oeILzMGGzBa@0Ilbm/F6StmKM1C8WL1xWb1spWhHh7TVl1t28wodmhv4Ls5y0JYNf8aWR3@GQV4K8MAb@Iyt156Y2EoqSq8nXl@b2zZYvg5dZUtZvGbNtoJ9Gv4nSc3k@1/6DU0r/N2f/NpF@6L9mQbKa7lcULXYz362PbWnntGr/wwA3GBwJ1BASQZFyzjoCBVXxs0Fm36u0CF3QWee2iik8/SBGouKKwMBxxzYRo/UWOEUhTJq2Ta3@dhLULIttMeRJiGfbKwlq4IQSMNciHcH3TTBYFto47rRSgrnwlcxCuZ8BopAVfjqAhQEjGCWd7ptz5q6Y3qXKUH51Faa3YUsUMJX0Z7mBtkR8ScMCTinsnU9K0fZI6qRAMdGhuehdU6Y64SvQhb/QwDWnI11NHmDKU0bZigZkxCeFNFrQNktKNviGdoUmqDa8wRpxrHjmWwQ9IWvgsxCVDBBlGHmNiSoAlv5KhAA6pDwAZstts2ySXZuplLVhenPS3zlAV/t0QNzGwJmQ2g9NO8SZK5iOggCBQM/PY39wm9hkCQjgQEQDoMfXKiBioLZyYfSIdnD@WBQAItszyWoauzu3QVWtZrZSzKqEcI/Mce41kbtYK/GFYAF6t2dXkVMMzSqWg1Cw24HFE8RutDrJG5NtRrJykT0XgoC/H9wp8UeeaWpKKKKFfDbi4@KLpAMMiPZeRt22XaNqVoxyULku4B7l5Aiowehztqc3ZG1z4LIS8DwZ7Hgw27AtI6j65d@v71qb4WBRD/Fr2qh1T3ODHw7KdyuHjK/g0mQO8wFVTEtSt03XdCm6ERFYNIzkVWTmG1hApXwoJcStBzDdwPySXxQLkzN4KmjaUq/nA0yqdV1oEG9sWOTLUuytYUvZkCPAB7lmwHkaE/tM/wKo982lDmKkUcmALHnI8Zkm9NBo0WUF08odFzQugPapJkxkFl31GNamSWoo5G5QjsEl6RMhHAHhHKkcccyRoDSc8OgNwq9iqIMQFCbdshm4xMT@tXwoQkzkO0pDziBlTPzxFSO0Ry65PTxxUNuASeGsh0OP37uwbePaDnOCbPME4MvSyeW7Ad5DNQSkKzTQNnFDwhbwWM5WjaNqyNqmqeCXxEeRe4spSN5NxLz5PVnVt1ItLFFL2i@MaFVLONUtyP0petC8PVxb@4FFsjIjhb45ZDlGr7toVocrYqERrUE35Zajcx4ybjdMU6IMTGwQYZOYewapww1awHnGGCa3cCaD45iqO1XaQKgsQcjC02TTtwK2qACTNxeogtDz2fwNrvDspqACbmBON@YG8DApq8tQ4c4yIr18CY9aBiZ1viRr8DoHPUgDq2f@N0P8we9G91kNnbRvdmGDw4nHSqrxviwCDz5iAdHB/ZnqvoGRBYAwxWYbCTEFIBNiUmRgw7zX83Oe7tAvKTCrkNKM4TgkxqgkKigI8tB25ORzyUKEHFf9/g3dXzDpWdnZzJZ0526pmx4@AlBz7F1SxkPTJCIHWVijMb@x9rNrjIO4C5cEv9yqDwejndmKNfWynfn/CkIfa/mn1VKxPteHCfHU/xC3mBElvfQ5J1HHeqhSV/X7Cb8o1O8/2mt9HnQ/yrY/6RS/BKBMIZgZul5upsGYOlO9yTdP@tV/YhTGpAAHFrRCALRxrUbeEZe4DLH/TCFM0E@GkZ1rBPaNAZIIl9GXhTNaxiknAde3z82Z5DJNs7Yruvq8wTFJzE1duDEnMQeNodpn2LAid8bOOcGl81ZY95ayj4Ls8OkFh6ZcNGsnnB@M1BufRvjZzx@BvEzHj9bFBoU25i1uEiGQZdYHez1aI01SIlg5kGaS26pehFDkEEeZyoHgSnnS2GX8OvWKHdAb@6DdqwFHQP6xBgIbiSUxstmo9myPeNsq5VSBtDZRSIEtDiAbrSIpme90I3Ut06tseMtBdlohBdmJR9vDOoO/d7A@wrWMWwg6hicXibaTR2M/LMdXCDwKwwQUA6DSBQNdicJM1kNzb1TJHSchrigMUes4SPTIunLj/LDQFzipOeEjQJqRQBheFglQBNiWDBy@AdjA@7wqetAmiCtRN@4HKH9vngrDpS8MlQ4r6lSI0WwkqQATSA7iqu1q1UJ4qEpGleiItW89Ns/iv7Gl0a/D@NiNfbUYfmEURWiQwUPZoII4Q8Xoiqr1yLtChgoW7pluDBz7XP51J@toZgtJVAzeDlYBe/MnHSHiUjjd5O8fejFVNEWK2FXmNdqUMV5jQ9LPi4CknKCh9k8P9s86Ah@fs5AAEZmZTbDzzaLZpvVapxxsNmabGcRJGeE5Ixn4alna5Bs@dlAezoIphdsnhZIp3hyVAR4Kp9GQQwai8zTTw3cgX@NtkVx68Ivc8FzqBf4fQhFbOxn3dbK0hsRpCNM6woA7IjXAPT4t@crwlWGp0qhL@RRnJQBj@I@vxtwXgEdjFhwldvfToSdjHRgEPjFFM0DMHbFVEMQVVp@xr8M/4npIDD4qdcDM8sp1eXATPrK3z9IYAspGxmgEelDzeSQIaMm88L2DddGZY4Y252CggNSXefM@X@7@7rttnFlzWvrKRDZaZEJ9efETiJH7si2nGh3YufYTrIzjltNS5TNjv5alH/USfY651zMC8zczyPMq5x3OFfzFHvqqwJIUJJlp3vP7FmT1W2RBFAoFAqFAlCoUs4cZZu@Fy900eJpd3Ba7PmwpEFEavlaGE5cs37AAY56MRyM/fHg8eOKLJpCZrt59cuaITzrDxDIzvLBT7peexBE/dyYOrU1OOuHUeApuEf9HOhlR6BDiWRsPVk/DqJMRtt0yTIWoIWvoOo2m2E/HDebDkwl3UpsQc6Wk2DPXC6D9S89WeVJPGmg@0NncPpr0Bq7t8NEQAld7ChsfXb2hzoR3jhqimRYi/R/Sj0nDUZFg2TlyM7qoUqfjh0On3I@6A3OSOu7iArYh81MgW8ksIGQPxwyLp7ysaStWGFFeJQ4Lc93ddGfvruo@mnV8d24/GoaQIoYnhpN0xiUHc2prnljdVLM1Hf4/fge2vgeLsaXV@HTOMvSvCqJ31f1IyeBQBkTNB7djgaaTnKrPYNOCpX4M/QqKXBnFNtsqdYGpjXKWtPZCx3iDy9@i@gtRvz9TfRf3IGmeP2u3efTsFeHE5I3PRh9iiedyJzDOpS94UL2zFYXs/bOHeuivAj7vAsVgtRYFlx9@NmmgYlAUVG8gWwA38LzMA6b4Xu2GKtK4hycRpee@rx6cxftNNtB158EbUfn9Cy4psUHtGBjeXW3hkPQsdAbyFrPobnLjVNpGgfRJVPlBpbxvUvXvZmtJEsYcw/vlDOGjZvph/QZ0YwtvqrsVtM6IJdbxnbsZYjtTwTIklAOXQk8qeWozD/Sk3CucTtBiA4ye5a9pFp3kfg8cOIm3WFGiPMW0k2Gp3UDEX6zZvvw@0h0e0upc61CVdPLmXQQo/k9Hi7qcYsrDE/KsdPdWPI2prszz1msJsASEbb9fVPIDGQYj7Rajg1RvizssUF/RibgG@/T9W@YVZpzBGpckiXdOOTlNusXbgYr4wb9YsPpPf0C4FkwbgpDmbZhT0vHclac0vOHltaiv5CSTlAsKgrJNRpWrox5puxfvsV1tm6sszVTZytVZzwC0lVamTKtVJW6F9A9i7qgG3TGN0hnJGHtTD@LxDb96w/8EXYrvuTCXCX0VO4yVyGBnAtylbpDQjnXzlV2@CHKVQ754XOu8hM9JGMr9zVXMcMCGUb0yg8v8F2LcLy3cpVtx/2WGfufg8jUW8hV4j6lPD/KK1OESIF2k9aII7b@QDdzPApoYmOl0lPgmMjD8on3YTz@v0T/SVgyDliEROxxPuDM6qEqpyYNa8aQemjaMAEx5ozkip7N6/u7bHwVZ0E1D2mNZ5dh8KSGL@fSwkgQQyqfaNAvIQi5WZmPkbJmsjuio2snDuVOTtcvARpZH2g7nH5MmU@SSjgWnS5v@isNQjrwbnii8E14zqBjqmOMcCbrzkELRP0lt6BR6Os0Lrr37R7ive50JsI2b7JILzFYS6aTDseHcxzicjBMMwmnwt4/tMvwppwMSnDvVDGWCnpk3pDMn3XLIBjswe8uao5VDqilRBASj0snMsrieYFlMZISWWdpqjL4CAVL5tAID1qfOc7fjn7kfCJuPJ4rbpqGTFmpkiVXWkxS4QKchV34Y6k9XrzW4ULs@5avpuQ19locALBKxrWIfB18h/4@EP3dKNSGCFMVzFOs50@ls@r1wll2CvNuUu1sByLRUzvuXOUoriEhOa0OLM18Ea/NqPgw@RAlXyqNoU9p@4Zs8ZrgFrpNry0EFrSE0WX64@dV@vh59WZCzWok3cuCUVoKqEnDkYbHmCZNW4yrNHxeFyOF97f97nd38CjdwXbnAR43YDRFchnlo4s@W7kkY5vEtnyBSC1XlAhyPi6Nuzn5SOKej27jY1v6sN882Nnfe/2RJt0nT564eo6eJPhh1GKvNZ7HBTJbcsfzwZxly6qHYFw47MZ2fHQ@GI3vfepnZ2SJCGtSBnyqxbCfHuOulmWWPJ8au1RO8loU1bA@J8PAT0klqDo@puxQ03VMBAnGzgNfAzHqLdHb49Way2Gnms2@3wuaTZ6@TBx6PYuha8yJuPv35XvFi2jE8dYlZtpVJsPONNTOvvrwqnakjl7V1e677Z/Ux/136kNt7wgeEN6@23rd2Fb0f33vsK4yKVM8xJfEgpLouhO0AkQNVqul0mPFkLcHw4nIHWfble@Hfk@9GrQCHFM9j/zei3N5KfSD8aaUqtNydII9zJDjifbCMewtOAAmLWOh3LT5jiKuHijKe0pr2h7WvL1BO@yElDeDte8wDCJzrU11Q@pBkrfmZrcnShJiXbLpEMewhQXWFRX3KT/ObgiML/ZXIDFySHDMdkFpwsX/vpuCR/WDN4cKHja29/d2GkeN/b1Dtbt/QK9vPzb2XhI9G4dHB42td0jijG/2dxq7je0afxAESgUF1xe/XkTjhSgUkJ2p0vqMk@/CkLo/fkvvekODV1c@39aMVO6iD@kT@t3w96Cd28hcRFBfcEOUjwqUs1I7ePme5nwV/IYTTnMUzPYH2XcRx19dKannXBsNlk0abxt6uNK0ly@7fB7RmyiEYAo22PuFw8@eMsDZiKcdBiq7DRsV7H2LkwweywY0VXSPYAOUMVipKg6dlst5zxnkJtXW6g7ggFVqEyNC/YKiL4ypyUaGKaZtZQAUlysafewHlTfiD8T39GFVVzseSQb1KP4gGdRj@QBVtAHbEbWmc1yM9y8gntW6fPi1N9zlY2H1JP6w5fMq9qnGSfqNu9RXcehJuAzpcoA82eXhIL7iFgZFIs6P4HHdrgyMQMKWkkyUo0S2baOcWRI2HRw1aLM3CQeOVOIG2An5nXGknKpbUEcwDgr6oYQmPOv6fTGBSkx3mPfUU/h4qurL4GEc0o@vqwwHzIAIJ5rGIy63o7XC4K7lqOTWTI2@tpHksLrGBO02BLZmEPgjYAhQPrXSafFMxRdoAWbQ0azsRAPiSOzb/s3OT@zcvmgFqQLaasv5Nfz9d1cT2Uutk4ydImNHXfR7MCK1ko8yO4MRjXEWqxwEDVKwdT4YjkPpQyfdAj5x4mmOcmNio9p@qW6magMdpmvsD/pWpafExTfUekpMeZdamePl7DwWX0l0bOJ8moTF7g7o@KeDy8A6O/NwiHQVYPuFFGE@K8fm52TMmIj@mUlkx98Uguo@rW7ubH3K/@0XD5F1RSxIYGtjdIj/iTFRFw0PPudjg8UR9C490kxExOjiFKW1DZ6WlhjlBhitA89DWte9aG7EaWJuPPsdV3mmv/PHr1@rUioPyaSjoUfnTiLdPHVsqvS4zInSJiCW7CRkSdY75ovHMGN5/QLXd9ALcDfUhxzBun0q3qAWIaZ1pxcdkiw67LPu7hi@qzbZosIokuIlwu6P4s/OVvXhpltMDEqURU7HiGjPQC67rmWWwvPVDLidxeBIft8d3NOF2Mn08F3QdhZC@y7c8g9vhiXTkgXr7mD/tgCsTG5/CCy13bsZsEySs9BiTo@Z01tZjq1pF9f4y0zf8dgjMJh7sYMSA7Vqu@jzEbVxZ@5IAdcGkyhEh0c79YMDlZX1CZUluYclQ1uLQcC@p94m1rZhn4VdIVaa4sVyrDyZLymLNvNv0WCeS7wbRIXWQTxNj1hYJE7TO@G1SD09s7AKwdb3LBAN5dLYfTEyKDrWgL/RGpCQTTrNamBmbjOXZfIJI9sIXNPNE93YtuFnC2uZuxFMeTSxAdk2Qf4ZbpbM778Poh9XTD2iYMHdEhrcJk2a5htaJxxSxUPKWCike3BBt5guhZG9KNjLhnYw/CqlNew/z1DMSKKEiy5siXWtHGvURD9eMWoOGyRiGvBh6akTxaKZEoyI5y/P7Q51k0nPSU9BpGQivO4Lmyuo@Mk3PYUxNeJ5shor5PZYW2Fsjg2WJ9id1bA3bs50H7bQ69PiYboqkrYLq8r/Y6qSWSJVk6H53MaYRIK8vrb26DbY060wxfN/FrbMIdPyc9wb0vo@ARlNIt7eJ85t7HkmPWGABaQT03ozYKYKkqozZ05JtZ0nIxs/wkX2hQgZhARAxOLpWl11PYXbfOgyI9nQOctMG6whHDdURs0M9b8trg4C@db67n1/fTLYkAmmg99glf9mMIqC5Fae5U/G@oR7@OlvwWjU52xyn6kHKA5fY1p42Y5v24nBq7QKiXzeZreko28nidmtZ/YauBLeXiwgSDl29zamt/fy5Q27qbuN13X1gJ1sdlJ7kdlR1rVkz72wvwgBlsG8L4Hpg@/w3Y8q9D/h4BmQRCa@zecwbdxbcWOKkNZ8zEGitFmolq3l6d7vRC2/Dw8kXvZ@pLLeD1SQd2Hr@7vuvJ310kaqPCEXDfsOlfKy@UKWi9I3bOgCUhqE9Ca@WxMWbmoYS0lcrzkbwD4KB1vBteyeseWkXyw/La0/y3Dr@t7Y6x0/O/EetKpZRZOv3@9FF6Or9uezwfllR3XV8NfT69bk99@UWnsMf9pq9Qfxl1xerxbZ4@wTBVfbz0rMuRrBH9n3M4JmFySasFI5lazDN@4plx940VzBDYkpLlUPeoYLccVuXO0dr59U@9XSRu@4f7KBS37jh9Xxw/JDBx9@oFmUZIyczB@PTzCn2ruuQf9SwZ8oR63VV0MUXw2hL2/8UTh4Xdt7mdqNgwKALTBt680b6hKgfAnWbLh7UugHV47eJvMUODYDBSmzxLeCyrj0zvvJ2I5ph4QZ9YpH2mx0zX8nbmapVLgYjgecYhxBgrXU1/BrZslcYyrxjgJlOQ6Nu0jcLyA4SR4HB0PydSJW1PmyqGtl3J10LRDHKMniMPspm8WdQiCq73Idn2SiQuC3zoFEl9Tqr1xMPX@u8EasFhV4Fw@mHP6IL0yUTvCIAxD6GfJpA6pgzT3iax8Zaj7ey3iQL7xHNeZ7Mmwgn2FNESkw/1Zf@H4Tl39OBBDCL4nOVdBbnFrzIkVS7g7y5gK8rKUX/jhmwLVK6ZQlNBawpb5qApwtxZlGqFaTib4vXYGcQiv6p1uQL/PbTDPi/K5kZ5LwObV@i0BL7lJO2sRPNynmWMXyppjJbJFi6VZqYKeLlkdvAhpWE7UddLuEtNBiKSEHHvl@r67/YVx/dIw6T2LkJT0/k55PpRckXZBKchVogk8yVexM2eUvSb5vKptk82bqqipWXgrU060CqSRJ3o1FeaPCeNAMk8ybcVcKV8YJz1MJeSvl5zm9Lyn3UmViBo/TjyVd8/eq7vkYy1TeF@n68ZvRHRSw8ay2NZni0kI/7P6Y0cHcdQrYLEvUVEqKc3hNZQZVVd/B1OKENDjs8/Ow3awmUB6WjcThMZPdfP4iW9BKxo/ONBpyi3FmYM0ZIxaVuM6HTLhrvrBI9XDyPQsEwwSjKTNyN03hiS48scAi1z1TrdyCnBng1LTpIV7Fvciv@GMGexo5k295fuKSYH4tjZfbzWkCsdC9l51PprQ0wXUR@agbtWAWSeqeTEOcLyT2rF3guM5A7mB3sA1@L5YTtqAwkmKG7nGKpnSSoWzY96YuROK3zN@LDzIvfdKxh93gWtWwzPD5FlYmdcF9HETjCD6o2D1OdDEcdnHqyArfFV@h1iEAVtdw3JJAtGb2QqYByx7J7@FJX0inQgW1D8hXMBBJEqKLszNcJsMN2MEVRCt2XMJxIVPrT2RDg8bMo1W5Zh4oON9gAdwNz2wkpOdk9IDS0dBvBYUM6WgRaT8ZaWon1FFpeT8d90bg6oymtEom8y8XYevz9kuc5z4plx6VLZJd6uPgUuHR4@SCFRHJJKzCW@Fa@XEmY50Nt@RsOA@AnnqNif498WZwGfT7QaZGMwZnjEhpjYLRZdAuZDIHQXwIDLhgZZxM4h724GLUks0dUrp8YkbcEo48OQ4jDsMv5mc5Lm7xWZmXwaFVctpMXX0ZtkFAc@OkM8DpMB9YwE2A0AOFesGYiPLAVWmU@OxZ48K6Sw8bUUQN@DmxziZiMvQH47BFPcM7WZkugZJjkKSyfnsKE6qv1fVxObgwDwFcj0koYBAwR0mLcMjoQ/PvwkHphpkzdt/0TJGk34DHCg33YBSS9E0IzL3CxSzcqYOPXjUO1eH@7tGH2kFd0fPbg/33jZ36jtr6yGfcOChnF8Dq1f5rki7xabqcmu/Th2ztkEpmOSFT2/uo6n99e1A/PFT7B6rx5u3rBkEj8Ae1vaNG/dBTjb3t1@92@PSdIKi9/SP1uvGmcUTZjvY9rtUUyyTl1P6uelM/2H5Fr7WtxuvG0UeucbdxtIfKcKpfU29rB0eN7Xevawfq7buDt/uHdYWGZXYah9uva4039Z0C1U91qvr7@t6ROnxVe/16qqH7H/bqB4qNBKxWbtUJy9oWLWFRE7dzp3FQ3z5Cg5KnbSIeIfjaU4dv69sNPNT/Wqfm1A4@ehroYf1f3lEmSlQ7tTe1l9S4jHMLVahftt8d1OE@CZQ4fLd1eNQ4endUVy/393eY1of1g/eN7frhhsq83j9kgr07rHsK8Sq5aoJB1KJ0et56d9hgujX2jmjOePcW9g4udfIHIgxhWaOiO0xgmEGgtUSk/YOPgAo6cAd46sOrOn0/AE2ZWjVQARYV20d2NqqQiHhkN1Pt1V@@brys723XkbwPMB8ah3WXOqxxiAwNGGR8JNahSt9xq9FPhJc8ErNmDOd63J2qsatqO@8bwFznJg44bGhuYbJtv9I0L8AvsLWJEg6wZ@D37I2VzuynywCeMGd3ZObv0cQek7b3d@o0I2tnV9kk4R3NOk@nXCnZaTTTxIn0mnJZ0w5OL86aYb8zwB3TuJhsfPSiMw/BkVwEivmUWRCbTO@vcIHl5Wbzfa1JC93DZtP17lIyhcZtJfQ2@KJcrm4jwj9g5Y2Nn0pF6P48RajNH/RBJxvq4QACOYX6P4jpm98LXFUstgNdDJf3AdhsHUVybHKOoxQSjXzZERFukip5Z4LfQ80OXNAx4AutJvZJYRnJmQYR/el/TV5kcrA@kHSW7a5iEYtYRiP8PTDVSCXsEoH/aI8EYYerLERB8PnMKdnVYc1fOBsM2o7rmjKcd0zrwDPHvaX4aXA2VTw/XZ6R5WNnHTkhMutuVmHi82dNMqX7pTDiljn40xzzj2uwEZ8P2DXlqnizWm9aOj9IcVgkeUq7tsD1Cu5k6Hxvan9tfMBqrrT6eGPq@6v4u4wt2AvCZy5NeMdc7oR/Xp1IBhpg7IuDSBJqDxnFolXG2JvEma8o4zkyXYVtWP7QXH0e8LxOJCFF9sLv2nViNh6F1zb2JIdfHtTebL3b3SXRCWwfP117sr6Rid1u/dWT34@oh93astexIc3jpKdxkjVKtknx4ZFieRVP2J8ZuFhERriON53GH@HnIbbbSFsyQZChuRHCPfVhopcNQIesYgcc9zKGX@eOTM0ATqqpLlrT869ZxfdJV2Ie0MYs3Qn32jX@AHY8/M0QjxukGUizGDv6Jc6l1QXLveyuMRXlxQ077kGWQtbwsbhxi2nAW11sP4vbtfymedvqxUhMGTFeudu5JCFxbxoLZewq@jKy37KfEb0BzN7D6MtfNb/R40ft4I7d3fnRuDY@JDLuxiWxT51sRutGH2vIJwjlAadqpqbnCrv8rkaKx57eTo4dg1ijgVFBXBrY@KYBb8R@RKarZAvYFzlXfRFOhfMOwNnQHKvfiXPnNUdD2TD@Q/S78UqhBFbs5ESodhXXkTFZPsZ@LAw5U2T6U/Rg@P9EmsyB/5xWnAQ9oZblBPBOlGSoQitavjJRwitz0GCdbiTUtD99TMB8szvmPG6YPr25lvs1RALdOxPz4SO7Pew4cwgAJsfGhj1@Y5O0c5@WTi@yri6Oc5J@qzd0lJ4rzFQxAze/fuKx2uWZsxW8uMqVvSarwtdUVL2Qhdspj3paMk0t5dX9KCvgXOP/o/iAN0DiAc9cei5Wq9OcVdKjzMgB7WrJmnDascckUku/3Xhq90BZLjJTsl@ffBlCEehN4DPbTo5pMlBinpv2uMgzsTpiL3hwXo5lMiYf7bLulA0xuwHg3G/zZgjCnoyvMEF0BTq76kugKec@G4qgksTqMPEzCHHrFoi0PK1exdjzziQ4NMb@XV/85geyq2VyFMTBh8bQvi5fUG/8CaHcvVuzhcWKDw4HHmwXUZlsS@jyCPHSGgxGpDr6aDfh6IUTt6A@6E2HoB9djLT/QprPwpHekTBKP1UDtUlW7zzNiMN6Ri0Kx7it0C4wf3CTegEsRMU9yXV@XTnEvIZHN82mY3j9sKyc50nKc6IJuyVlIj5X6@rrV8klBNUuQwOmYBjFiwu22eR6cO4QD7@rwegz5n6oQP120I49k1ogeS9QOqnRZx@PrbE0fTiIeEeDugI7IDElyrKRFhuq0hz9RLOTtmvKJt4x4buUW/L99cRMaqylqKKEcXXtxHzreepMUGlVuwaNnYWWV9cYlXkLrm83LsbYW2j62FplP/VjkVIRJaJ636iOeBK5GT99xJPe5K/ejzB66AvOuLUKCoShs@JcdVbOMX6wKfgQBqO2vSdKmkzbH2L7jZc@gz7zotk61G7/Wv44Cia0AmgVw@siw2g6fxmc95vbg65/Fg5Cn9Zp8DZ/LRIPjxN@RIedjQZXEUcvknCMVqb2JHkW/zLihg3v8bnkhuWaKxoHQ8c2UxiPJrVzcRPBO@cwAkxisDJ/D6d9pMVlHq8lhTLp@6dsj1d2N24s@6g8r7Cc6AOAFnCbUxYUcod0zBeTrMunGzMZThdlsHA8VXnluzdY7KUwfkYk4mOYFMYGmRmzBLsRWJndiPFx@9prsw/CERwtBTsBwu9EDn/2fMTBJinyIywFKqr8tGQVlVOUa/ghxMPkZnKvPvknY08I/An0y4/mccs8RmAR1zHeliJZr2gvo4QLmweGLKNZEpMUC8/CvnX9kGNdXE9DTSdPbqIGW/6QUqTd7M1wJUakQwsfBNlzmiRymhMXk0pO5Vz22wEVpDZ2SjczbHCb/SwPfhziys4ZBNO2huxYSN9EqhZRCTGCp8xrbZTFp/LtI2Z19a69NkXA6jyTMyvitZM1mgvfQAllfsWx1mBEwjg7RT1t6pGLxoNh7o7Uu1F2zPXMNo/WLde91RBYmK1Kk@WDNpO2OsHjZCMzjc8U06QpxpZmxENYvvJzzObTRLyuNjHeqs3JLXS4iWaJ3VQ8qcT93Zaxj0nxEha9ZqKJhxTjDielG/H34yY1vHmzBNEwZXnVZInRhMhoTuTRAjVFpphKd6cQc5/GfYoebaIc6m0T7ez@uZGo00ZyxuWpSUo5uQQ94bgdlzZJLg07ML6AmzjRcGMhFSuc196Ej/LK@VM4GUaCAIRWHOSTfSjZwU06a4qPODpAx2nCWqgMSURPm7aFQ@z0PyYYe@XXmzva4qE5yZdPNgTSdQyJVhWcaxEkc9@cXo@b1wxlhhQ0xOeQIm7RjGw6v3ur/mxbKB9BkNKcrC19Sx4a46qHhA39sZOa19CBk6p0ydSISg@EJosGGgu0SjnrBrJchfYXjoTjYd2ghxEtIOSzg5@HugTcea@XYmqjyHV7giyuJreMNlflN6VIwlDyDvLroSiqLi9cCUAgGFP5apkgwK0pY49DAXa9Y3NeClHdR1SwWsawpI/sFTWx85yTDqLqDI/XrByleTme2TDyc4GQYjE/T4II6SzzsyRQaKKbi4uV48n89iQ5SCE2vC8Up67QvZKmYdxzQkCOc11yE4lyXFZeSXMwJz5ec1OJMX9z6rOSlVqaTiX6xBge58vTqU9LqdRUtaur6aKpkkQP1641lUikcG2EY6nw5/7x1RTb5XlsE2otMlJahrbPRhxyWmXSuq3wa6Se86Vso2MYePbNcLP8akqIlZRT9sUO2FWOjwzgu/1Pt9ZYphpMdKwA9ktnLrs4siBkjTWLqR7NwkrXeNqLHRSYNe2go94f7e6m3L6eToyhUS8YrZVKJTDxqe383thWYyspHBTTuYudi263OLz6y@j9aZFlfxBwSICKWUEH1CU0KKLCYHQmkSGAA2VF7ry@yIq1/kWnY4dgwAklOo@6TXJqbwiKJ6AwNnp5f8QbQAxST7C/oIFo3y8qHn1XviiaGoo5hqLSMAm@zJrTMyIPPnRgnx2fVDEwCGZjzUTzllvd/IIZBJFNuLPYfbH7JTFPzr4Kut2Bpz4g/jE8BSx9my6wu2sXKEkWnDDy7d6LiP3Reiq4DLvWvWJksXkd4MzEZOJMGL/w8I1/EJzVr4dO9vjnLE0r1OSHaOZD@Kf2VPYs62pn8XcAK3xIaN8pd88fOi2m03Rmmur1CE6eCKNHZW/u2ieVxeU9MU2z23ODqPPRLbCzBmq6y7qA8WXP3cstuSF7TNzsp@tyBzQsCQyNE3yu3K0Erpr988Ti5bjTuZtU5DAA0rHfJRElEsqfE4h8BsAjUA8/oie8aP@Up2G9O@VQRBQcBOuYlTso0ESBTOZ@q/rblVOr1dTK8OFDVatt0UM@r2pbNbWDD1tbaofet/D@Q3V1bW1DZO6O@4U@bpmP39QWweAdzoet89EOvVJaFffGYK2NLl4pVle8jZVm9fnmRlQ8rm3hWj89/ee//df//Pf/Vqzpl/@Bly1@Of45zlQoFIorrS8rP3zbwPvxzklu5fR4ZXiSO9sAl/2dvYYPGuO8n5iPFkanmWWZBayvbEdq1tnsfUYXVSamX88ffSbpUlHLrai4rL9GEjmKZexyK7C@B7hHeUpLeBN0YHopT0gsE9AJtuOpd1oBDPBoviFKEi6wA5XycrZiNu7hDibOEJ@qLGtPPKyzXga405J4UsBdXJqx8mE/CvrYAb9knVeal8n49BuOm5p/iz@/ic62BtfqwSdHPSipB556kM3yT3n9GX11V4ohbudKNloOZLMepSRHCzAzVFHIih6vHzjWzhS5M5kVDtkDSMZNBWeWW3BevPrjyzIScC06yywh4qeSLRI@ZEKR5S8r/W/ULV8ox7ds6qoNKwpNvYrhyqwTlbh/oQL5kRgCJDX3hCCVAVWJkz6@kYynovmi@zrD0YQYMMh68HKXxz0@0Fy00tc2z6m1FMIcsfm8fMXcuCGXoRltpEj9CQJ8oCLLyRLfJMwt5zJi5W21kpspt7Dt9mnmE1uHSTA2tulS6G/KYgKx5rYJt9LX91q0Ibccr6hsGB@vWFVlp22/VcYq0rvojsOhvq7AtWNAfYlr@yYjCT3KgASO@OyvzI4w3igwnqKmukWCZU1Ue4Cmy0jo66vp1MFuQU6OLCIUf3ZobH@dGttukW@JGHYQHmCkYlO@jh92I@11ZcTEPvNHp4gO6Hc4oNpYzs14Pw@RW6cwHnRipAsMmU3Ok/FMTVkejvyznu@p5b3B0cifNGjaIs1n3Cq41EK4YAISGHy66nnNMwhLi3SXMEXiprDlEIIXdCc6PJr0bTa@c4IuNUNBu13BIEixE1My@Jrqqyk6Jlz9HZ1gozwjvOPTSC1iWfLC0khDytrXZniYzQydjKnBHjvxwMlmBNV4ZBpe0IUuMNH2@OCXJHkXPgJ03Vl9C1BfRVh/hvoxO50FfT81OQ27GXPRv7ihZF7EeOZQlGKNlNFQnpSTiHfAivTIn9NeIGRuMu6MMkuOs/Qp0uHclu15hJ18x7b4RV@FcQA6DmDGN0PUu34ownJqhkpiYBRUgy3/CUKn658RfpMrfwJW/LTs/Hiv6B7//Kl/8sD51P/66XeXMdEi2cyyebWsD7ONxNJjhWbGopd6NVZpkXE1@KmfzvCpr@QOi0UCQqToHP9cPPlaJIQ@Lbvug@KnZSFIqsuASXFxfUWAL86guZzGoricWXIfuKbznR/LrqK5lX/Rh/LBlV/CwiwqeZue1jmjDoHie7q/XciVk6j4dLX0eLX8mFZCZ8F1fhRcYL7NRxenwTWpEhGWszT1fPo9xQ0pQny7jvwN@nhN7ZSwJnL3JNKXlLQI1cOc68nEbEVlCsITlJ@ozO5SccXFjfP4OHzEgt9TxHImL/uCEtNBi/sczJ/RoId6/Ahybfp2iHAkrAzERoS3UPOAbIKv3MShrhkuOb7nVFDb8N3KQKh7i8vWbNEf9PNaWXMLuQ0o0bg1031aelqaHqMzQzQ1Qle0MpW7p8qbPz75j/@@/9vyeHlztfhhRL/j5d@W158uyyM90Nsj83a5vLn8HNnWvy1PirQGpscn//E/qfzmXwgOUibP6c/mmoG1PlnezFe5yNflzXV6KK@uUr3/61//ldqwIis2xGJdaXqKEdswFNn2@8y7lK4aaKUsS3OJWOGLWYAhFoa0NqcXGEZdrz4t8TbdsraquAy05ytjj6KneDbMGrOpkOxkGHsK0oykQBUV5AWkMaHoKMt2w5htgHkTNNUv9wvrEa0AftHmHHGVsenG/QgmQyuyLKIOdKRGWs/Lw2bpx2xs3lHJGpuSDaNCYmmnZe3TRxvEDm8HwThspa0kzHDttfyr4LQAPiwE7QtaU/Wj7uDXUfGSWLJXXn1a7GBzv8h23MUhQ8oPJ4XfSRHUwYBoYchGp54aUQ8MenDh5XG0IFLod@MzKRNPkrTsYdCSPax0TGLKInf8PDkeRnMKiSrt8F9S4BE5UweCtGKlfepTyf2Diso@jDNKPl7zusDmLRvHahcYebGGHbJsKmS4DdgdNO0p1EZnfAmJS8HrumQp@O1209dpTmYpa0KleZml86A7rGY74t4dvlNxYqLpL2rmjVDyIXYQ8nkWdIDVC8Y@LdGrWf6C9XhSA9yk6LPW2FVcQtaOzqtX9e0qR11ZUPWVVH1FPQotIakn5hnLG5uys4lsqWKrchQ0caQ2t2KqLTJBm0cF/gEGkXRLo4NrCbo5fAOSqJY0R1uV2d3m8VqYeOQqkDt7srUokaszy8nlR8/kkBvU0J1Qb0EqIwEBL7gVWCjT@6HcgKiaMKNhPyP@/KaSjX8PDYbbsA9XorbbOnE@KtNS/xKxb8Ix36VURALtV9a2wc7I7BGDjl1sxSFos9h4ybpgqU6FF1uc0XRHhcNAG5dQ2azsUx23VBxetqOj10qgCPqQLZVXHz1eW3/y9BminC3p1s4Hg0IFrAKG5z7BYI3aoUU2vler2VxWPiEE9WyVgD4PLA7gYNZ15brG7fOVe69aLmlgpSzDuuIwGlJcb1cyyATiKChgRqA1ijPKOs6PlWM07ORT2/1K/xN/G/@AzHDGHa0vpLf64W3imSrTE4cDVRbM7BTHeQQPKq5OsfMGg84BvE0EsHUVtqeKXsMDxPh8NLg4O7e5o6BdWx3RgCGCs19qrKBeBuPEwZiFFXRRveHQsG5fVA2849kWwCgXUwJ0PgFOw0z7rfS1pSlGR44mIXjWxI1VHCFapqM2OzN39geqvrczjdiyHYaO4RZsy1ZS7tiTGRzIIFav1dwjoq72dsFXSbVM8lJelVnAlZCvzNfhfdyVbiEQtUUVI6tZbxg7i8hSZl5MXJsmRakfgdccmOXS7aQ091pNK0AQIwj1blIsxLz4PMcmWYKT3ckYp@DlbMWyEX0TRhE7mNOVZV1tUcqZOKrAUuYGgNi3KWWlIaUKepQf6xx4WXobwRzlVjS2BrQZcrxSDebm5DATbHUbiQNsRB03tED7G3vbntqp05/dDzseFOWt2k9odxzi@WZ8yxrfckU1dk0X2N5i2eYWNlO/4YoSMUtJO4xNEITw7UhUxCDxGlBv7Gray6A@To3tk4QrwK6@VsLN7qgeJHD0wnsgS3rxHrvi4Os6/K0im1ezkiZ2qaKHhWxxLR7YFk2WklpjSELKO4BYnQYRO2pJuH0pYXixQGfN29drF8PYjd35PJ1iWVlQkdq@WySyp3n2RsosYotVzRarFfTjIr5gvl3IG6dBZ6DvosXMcQtv3PtjvJG/O3Pk/79gjvo/hzseae54VIHsEe6I3YbzjU4Owz6YwzGnE56Dm@3wLMT@UMd6RSNKngWABR4wxB1SSiyX0LYbxIly5ic8nJ6PYCS0uoaLAX@o8Y914x9XIHP5cSf4f7Xx@X9w49d049cqmGvm9LxW7Sx36/@YFicqoZP@MLd7oe5KNvePtnRdt3S9gtl0Tjf/X29p/v9QS5/olj6pwGOCHDiI@/rF3CyaSO1wu9FIzC0KGe20y0Ec@/lc6WLt1a5mafHQ6V5E51Vo6@oP4/9U4/8U0oifEIYOZxGxbWi8lpflqVyWF82SdzkULllJS6S9xjO61V49YSXrET1BiZDmja2RXqiQQu5JYnLaVEj0x0T6xpPPXXEW2a6DZeLg3FpAy4qw7CZDXDRfHSRzdT2eV3bYB7LaPjp4/fC/CBl6/md9C42QR9deBd2umUnsJdhR7HVKN8ZqDmAf6jVHilU0ORnZsb7tHbPL0s1SjR1bTM2L8xcJctSG8z9aS/Wgb1hRubFlRLQp6PJmVQXTXLO8kC/Udsk0v8m6xX@IS59pLn1WUQd6YXATqXy94ad5MVmnra6tLZoDpFQBPxiAJY/yLxhV/xs)

Based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210373), see explanation there. Whispers doesn't allow any
additional spaces in commands, so to fix Whitespace I added two lines containing two spaces.

```
>> R2
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## 399. Befunge-98 ([RubyFunge](https://github.com/TieSoul/RubyFunge)), 16640 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                            2222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11         xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
























































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullasge>Ex Cr Uithary,8,3"t"F _^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML42ya:nlet d=/;~ 16mb|>^ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({4f775301-bc9f-4381-8f94-d878a3123141}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAAHxTpEqlUt2q2/XqKtW9102yWCAJkiiBAAsgJbIkVXR7dnvdtmfW09N2tB/j2/asZ9vriRjvxM66vWPPRNj7ccIxn/wDyo@NDceG@x/0nnMSAEGJlOq27YiJXUgE8nny5MnMk@dkJg66hj/6yU8SeLGnrr0Y2u6UTU1/yvqedWJ6MruzYLcNyy9ouiBgqn1vOBubztSvCgmmMmYbznBmDE02sOyp6WWZb5qsa9ruKcRrjO3OnJlv9hvg0xlzzFP2wOlZfYDApu6x6VhvTQ/i8ozdNe3z8fmU9dzx2HD6Ppt4ljOl2AJjTw3wDGa9Y2Z0/aln9KaW60BUkbEXjm2Mu32DUfKJZ/JMJQageseUZzWmzNgj1/NNKMHtmb7vYmAFAg3Pch/uP/74Uno1xz42AKmJbc4vFa@q7DPL9PqXc2js06N79y6H6uxrkuuwe1dRUvNsfzZ1H0wvwy@w/aHpGEyTK7J2ObIIxJyadjlXzl2OKkF7mlOrt1IORNyzPGhdI2hF1jMcaC1syx1mjifTBZN4@xu2HbWtzwyfzfyZYVM6Zzbuml6Y0J8a3tRyhuzUmo7YdGT5UT5K7U@Mnin1TdsaW1Ozz2wLMrmDAAqAdvrs2Fycuh40eQDTdewFZDR71sDCLCEeABCv1HRkcjhjYwGN7EyhczCD@YCGbYbQ0kIC0t81u7Mhc2fTyWzKALe@5RtdG4B2F6xvDoyZPc2yLsQBkSn8dGQ6QWcGcDKAOHI5Vq9nhJq57PNGv89y0I8Bj2OTWUA1QqvKdB3CmesB1SBViFEAjPo1r6M5hzaDJhq4VVbI5SD@MApBbA3bdwNkVlHDSAfGKrUZwn3quUPPGAM1@ibR9NMHT5nfcz3wwQ/T8vF0HZieMWW7uyx5@PhukjWiZpG9rhA1UZ2dQRMkwkh2Ytgz6CHxlnChfbwot4BNltxKVlkSyKLlWD7P8jBsy0wrAJHUXAUcMP41XYVfkWlllldhBBWYrpWSWSxr4BlDyzY5pCFCKmHnhyQa3HN5pqtlnnLo2gOerEcFlpheZsUSKxVYCe4VVtGgRASfZ2qlAL8i/ABaBdBR4afnOaBl34e@iv3tgA2MsWUvAugEvscKKisBRMBZBchaGSDAU9fxp8OP0Fq94rCnI6D4yDgB8JJtHSNHMiOmhM2owEPZ2VGIKyLb5cX7IyweyAeEK5RZCYovAiXygAJQVytD8YUcr4g/Mm07yDbyMRthW8rBDzAvAR3K0AI5oGUOiVmCH/iB52nA3DTgZBowJw0YiqaBW8ciIF0R4orQnMWAXiPDP4aCeDlan4gPXB3AqEhtZGQqEgkgQGsxHdqsyPLQGXTsDAWdAf6AS6nIgJeVVVbOs3KJAT0rOQZtowJe2FNU4KEq4KMiMGh/FTqACjipQG0VgKp6gQkxYqs6xkNeHfICadQ85MmDGxpOLeIP8kHPUKFIFcrUtMqyIwJuWgHqW9Cph2pFaN0SxAHdNMBVg@6kAbZaGeIxbxloWMYODN2WE8JAOkCrYJeHfgjEKAA@BBfSglsr6Zx@hj0ZGV3k2Dxnd4BZizgUikhGyJrD6sEzj9QEVHIABkcBoK9BD9BpxMAzHxVvqwCkieDNvkVM2raAf6kRhUpZ6pCvjcl0STa1SBhNFtNRFKbxMBeYpwUM0BwavUUUCaMvG0UuQ4s6hmrEb5eAcnkM9YG7ujPfXgKJHHmNijJPLHsZVqawvmn0B5Y/erfENU@FdE1j6ljHy1IKhWyMqEYsoogRK0ElPZ52akkwZQ1H6FrWRSthmokbNdAKyqpK6HXNwcwZmlKlHMOPYqYzbwqTy7LMCg/2rOEQ5uUlHDVL1aTJchlcIAxtXZ8KUSBSF8v0LJjCb7HeCISKKLLC4VcqSxi6hjAWRhdndgkkMZgJKjh3Daw5697q0cyxRFAnOvVG1iRMXN2YONa4VMi8XIz1DaLc23IuYs14teXXruWkkiyZFi4EmG@4dBmfrWFS@wxnKpx7sevC3OqS5LBknyknnB3TQLTViR5mXhvYKDRKz8BZGOckk@bUEI41lRkUAqKg6Z6g6EoT40oxPk2eXQ8lVZB0@qbnMUwL4q2fpWnWn3V9880MZaklXgOYt02Y3geGZUcI0DxiTEkIgGfSh/IWq2gPPHdMk80Yp1HbdScbRBaYtE8R0H331FyivpzTjcnEBskJwk0uuAEypwbJ3CSgx0vlCEEmzAcNDgCpKJA4LM/sEe2DqkNuHWSTVRSrTGvc0hHKnZhIpcNgAXHDxzzOzLarIOuYPaY3lL55omAIF7tWxS3EIRTEQJwKQHQNkJcRc8IignRLk0nEOwpb1nfHq1Xj8@uDqOojC4Uj@9RYQOsNYGo158YYpHqGojOMXDaGHsNbEFsC9Bas1gPWd53kNIJy6oEgC5WOakLCMtJkao1N0IBcyIItniekcXYnzLoL6MpErbxMKg/H5BKhZOEyoXhAPhbABwuIfP1ZD6mGZVsO9SAQk3yU8z1glTxMmHqs1TLg54FMNwm0PBkdmPA5ohZTEnw@2gPpu0cQUU41HR9UC19mFupg0POH7gA626kFdQeGBVmXsHtEBCRBFDSXe7JAJMcOND62mcV6kwmDcJiUoHvey5VBDHVfW@wtRNojUCN6M89bsPkEWsIaQ6ppzx0MoPe@NScjAMHGfdZb9GB4QiNj7xH6LjGY3mS1mkvftglpHFRMDp7@LBuaQHYQWgeooWKXX1ZgMqEqECkMhwu0jgGUwir0Jgsii5BY5hi4rozhfdf0qbO43nE09LEw3xzS0IBxNlgyozEK6NBLHVIs@sB5guGF8LFAYW1lsKigF3xsOjB0etArYdBD82Gb7rMBKNoxERZ1DaPXMyfToJ@4xM4sJybzP7mHMj@FSgEw2R8J27fZ7qVeA0mjnhOTZVEHQtQngSpiIK8NtHmJBI9I7eScxV5cKR5SnFwqXXyFaVYweCVuwGFCQwIVIGISsymyEuSOVm@EvHCK3IbkbRht3uxq9SEsXrw3ZtIgKhuxUYHtCLISBSEem2FI8LOvApInNsJqrARg0pWAG0Ab/ngNZDdC0u7HQ2XFkIEp3gR07DruGqhAzAguJlmNobagzvgcuYZhR52Rhou/0kbIsJcLTDiRwRw6mbgejAzOdBa0mkBNFutdgRKeiuaKtMzurE6tMGUkccKf4iwIGSa2AX0BhxiOVNCsDOAUwMS4kgw8z@UlxhCmUU@wAvxOifXzzgRzqeOYqJwZ3oIDgerB9AwFLZjlecAGT3CS4HNQOJnI1E9hTjD6feSsSA4a95cLl7FHH8y61vyyJt7DQPm1L5wYHhugEu6B0AGDKJUc@Ml0jcIpZyxKVNzJVKGs/C5CQkokQ5OnBqDXwyRxDxjN84XTS4krQ0zMMnE2HZTFNDgwI5fR2CegKlzGDtUH7DTjYxjX5KuxIUzfkgR3CcMIE4xQZIwwPJAzYBCCllmp9LsGOwfu4TFpfsBVkVAlUeV8VJbp9KOyAkIgLvH6yrwI3@uRQ4rNalgDTE41p0lihYAfSAnKKEKAogRzKwaQtMfjSK7hgTOH1uJYiosiaXYWCb8wAaQIGQuED6tnTTuBuHLrVii4bNXr0NlAmgK22U/HNdpw0VIGTg2JZZJGgkLkqft8imMjlYb6YuILjg2ITdBT6w12Nh15MOLIfyFAIiCr4GBPDgkbtPNj63jWv9zQDgZiIhFHHQhNVm8q1gSY/PloqF9H1eQKVUHrTSJVsfNifgJ9pfNSKDaoGCTzTB/F33qASqyFU4hB0FfXkohnDcKWHfpg0bMDkYC7YLBzbtQF9I@DxayIEWUDmSActFdGKgeCw4HDYU/3j@7Xg7HII5Wu5VRXAmy3Z9gUvI3JxTDvwwd3nu0/@9nOGhi21a1eDlCsfLmIU@1sLg2dmZKXtep2HMYS8N3O9bAx42oaUQiimeTOY6LSogeTyzwk55NnX7tMEpCEkBxUArjxd0mk4WlA6BK6hj@6NAmzYSYDRUZZwrRMesBCmJEDUcd4I8Tn6eztW2y8y0hNgnDEzJ4ZHEAYqDxwwnwyRl4SwMKo7oDPiJQXpFDLwc2GpSueMsTnY5SaLyNDonSsy3z85N7hszqBDdbVJEqi@FOQpQyvL0Oft2eggq9LA@wPXD2WkZeIozxNuK4lcK@3QuBl27IN8AEA6jqyyyR7HFbNHwHuB5frRqFSL@oB5CcIl@XKuDzU@7KIxvDAKa6HKu@6WZQilpNVFLR2xopiV6etXqFglvKV@LTVW5bZjwOljQGYB0K50YOoY1/CEHkpRQZidYD@84dXEPdJiARVQAox820mU1m@LaD2Ilks6SsHoKG5til/RhxPZGJaUZLh3oDc80n5jKU/nFvTVC7Nn2oa0kLp@/sPtLth4mDJmlYySGlAXRxnJm@Ae3w9H/qI49ru0GU7kIdLh2GBIDZtrOb@0HWutJCBgVjVBG4TAv/FhRtjAnON9ZYUR8oVV1f5hqPh@KfApdWijkQiChEohdLLr40TA8i1rPfzB984hElELeRykTtHF5AglofIha5eLJQCmAQFyQE@aysYbRleGe1hhBTbs8NKB4wuyri/jF4bSBxTVtamX4vSJ@4Vir92F5e6FoTwrgWOGMkePH768MHjw0f7n7emWqGw4s/nKkUgHJTXBVlIHnG64Wjd4UMTq4XgEjA2PBxewAVmoKCEO0Yz3wPGLWMSmSOwodfwzdbUJ@7ISfrpy5U5xVjptdPjXegRDj6eNMgIinbfRmXE4zvWOJ9j/xlNpxO/qigwykezrgxKq/K659rGUKF8MDHYtqKi6vLgCa5r@OtyADL@wuQ5@OIWiA4LWkE07LELygvteyNrYCkOnlatbGs4Al0YN8dNLy1HPZhqo/RBQwBdWYnqRgyYfEDb4Bm2k8i79ldVrcz7tZrT8ooYJlsZ/pB2a2CC6pSC2QpIkb7kZa1brVtsAVwaIV0GkmDyDi1y@AznApuBIEmrpqjnh8QhboHrpcgriEZvZriaC1xKKeTyJbVYUEAtAzUNZFYJ19yksTHtjaSpKwE8yR3QukGsFw78nuEM5J3AESILct9HUFW9@bLVctogoLduEW6499xctJtqO11jV7PsBOnTNei9K9XDvhsGQN8lJ3RNerIN/KxvXGVnfYNGV58p0/EkmHOkCXu0D4LUWxf4dd@Mjz3MoMQjlZ2VtAomfqesWRCyMauAN6SUAgMKZlroegriJYHQi@Ih9BzgW7EMbLmaEQlMi@kI@IfOUgfkSl@VcDFYD7jGKiq4KCxPFsDyKBEybUlHhMIIKnDCISAqSVCBUOLB@CRHgR8zibEy1Ptx6Flu0qdtGhStcMHWn0A70np3DycKH5copzBBR4MPJwroXzhPsFMziUv5hs8XTCFTcNQgzA/qYgSBNgaiRXEnOlwB/ZBy0QoBMC/o2rhyO1oudOK6A3R2KJBwwvUPEGIc2sAYQiUhM6/IPq8IL4lCVqt07LinDkLrmqwsda0p329wZx5uuVv9eN0gua7xNACNKhebWmhvvmv2@EIvz0y1AD3UYGNz7OJqBgh4xI1MqoLB9/VRHfVx0RxGdk7CTUuAL7HbB8BIeyZfspLGqMdBrz5kyamn7EvfUAzpLQyoa8Q7rHysiYNGPwoJsHrKghZqgkVYEpDcMSX6jJZ8MPJOKHEHXQt7lmjU3YnpXFY7uVKaStfoNEQyyfehzpJbW1vJarKRzIJrD1y76NpDVwZce@SSyIXpZHRRjiy5MLZJOTCsnbxohpDn6Tb2gTkKL2@tScpoVqt6O2s01eCp4TMNTQGUh9QSPgBOMl2vozOdFhunuG0EKkSs7gfYd573PGsSkOATkEm4Pz68xGB4eWYN1ePrKTKue6C3mijlprxkq5lrtVtnrX6mdZHMYu50zaiDigr8c5oay0PPnU1AdmzmqxKw13RTr7Zr3Xoyl9xJpcqSDQUZ6fRH5XTG4LROJU3oU6lWKwkkDajT7I08gjfPaul0RCjAY2CBomPbqaR8Vobyu@l2OpOEvOlkFmaGejIJdKE9T58qjYsSvBPds@ZAShiYMMvGtzWIR9P@GA7Xb5iT0cKLJ4gW/kDQx0X85ZEZPFmEE0mcUb/l@eMy5cpiQyh683QgX@P6IYpskwWfYASOaUtZOaAVTv0n0mDsTg3lUxn0Njk2Yye3kookwWRMMRwSVfuR5eMQNhzTnfnxxc61a7BYOoQejWbALMNTclnoVdZEMHsjlyW3bwN0Fm05IePH3TOJ78GFAPo9GX7IRFEwwv0aEHDoXJMFfJFOhNHCkEpIcNYTbg8UipM3clRajfKwHBZkDR3XMyUgCeQQ6BAXHQ0UGuHW@ANafLsy/QSxNKviVGaZwBHv2a5BtOXsOrYlNRnH8jtDzPLM7As28I8BsEeZt4Vn9pUdgTaKXW8EMwTUBjmxFrXWOIhQXH/Sl6dzyCqkcM6PR3IFE@TeU9bXNK3YKwyqYRz2CiD2CBoJFWMHtOwwSlIhMh008iFfmQqXCR4/uXvIl29ovscZHpfyOmO3PwPRNlDdnpnOMMsOoT9Zjju2gAxh/rfH9jPXnfKFBvBsWhziers1ntkGLTtdXhm6Nl/P7bo2rUZdl3WZfub5hm3wdbAwdv/TR6BuvDh6XpersUSKcTK@tmxcCl1fLKfng/i2J235hjtUPu@Y4nZBxHkrPHyKbCaIKGLELDh6Cm0UhpcwPBxSuI0ThJcxfIzHTkFcDxYyyBsFBgkrlBCPouK5uyDwTM1dYPhGNTBKp1I6LrsusT1TNQo/mQ4GK8E6BR9LyJrsZXCegvmR1BU1NY5SgSfC86kraeKAipQmOqa6MV2J0vEDNnK0ufkoOgcxMu1wd/MZSCy4gweTvo1yFehNqCXwo6QmCPkT3Kgh1o3bf6wHcrB/RYqFwTaReGohsUUDCCY3BUUaYVthwfJ7jYaQ4wbbpj5nq66X5Ss7uw2@0Y5qncc1SoVvDGx3AMRuoxae@duUDEtKJqNkBJVwgxxUTTpbcKWq0UkRn9b7BcpSE3wFNJq5lpNa89Jh@zyp@ESGARNbrflHOe1zUI3w0Ob2LWVo1uiY1QZ61cKYZCDDdhdMAokPU/G1894I@AzLzFdJCe0zcwau3Zf4Rh10GMZVPGyg4JxEdJg0ODNsWl54jpQO8vKsyF9jR1CvwL3UpI2rCWKHViNAMHzO2Plx9uScNWHKO5H9iW1N2@xCnrqdUXBYy7l8vJXLoJ5nLHwhOGZTZ/vPPv60mWtzCMLYwM23Mm/FeXhKGgRnEJTwODu48LDQ1JqSJECHISysryoDUnPapwH0AQYvoMaigoIaIern5vmyLgMTlOWUiZj7i3GWmekLeWAb06np8D7Hd0A3k5tvVQXF1Kn4vWDfo8pytDkEkqmFcYBijT0/unv47JkMPddPJQ9xE6kKw9HojUBA2VTpkJLxylfZR/0k@wjzpHHlQIChBtpHJ8gPnboGnR70DygdecfQ9FIQmMb9nx4E05YbZeQSWkAgPPLVmxKNImApMw11ImDVtfi/cLiqFeBZhR6fIUoCuVO3qkBbKy3PHOuN7MNEQ3IrJAmUVZgv6tsp4mLbajo40zfG3WvQsEhohBo0m0x6C1wOEous3a7xYwiQFhUwb4jUFUVqCjpMX1fDpq9DMIg0BCHIXn/HXjZzUqWd2V4His63Befgef1jcBHCKmjfXFvsdorG@5WBzHHg25Gcc78gdfrSSyBVts0dIl/2puThmS1iOnTEa/Wo1upBMBhkyEpoNQgrErKERPCWQtBnKZ44P@g8mI0CUml2FhFdQ5Kz83OiIdvWGNEQXCrjjXERap/AmB66UJuHwRsKcemARmtwlgXHbEsQQzVrdbMYY7gIr5xckk6lEzGej0uHlnPs0pZT5OrkZLWAEmGUe3xsX82J52DptpI0woGn1TZh54@7A7qtSUA7L8GePgXQmn4gC4MQaSjP6EHL@2tKXj3HslJscEKWZlpwM@nNDSmlSpkSD7pda1NSIAIeTQufa5IBk8L@rMl5WQ1fecClGJiPgHFx7WVZ9ctHoNgK3YOjvMHzv3yzD/S/2jojmChw8TNydGDqxpaSBhsbK8iKHrqtb1i@Rj@zLYMIQ66bQPYMD6pk2JFjPWg6ByBJMP2PcVcjaHHom3gDqfGabsYx55uS4XN9Iev29Rxgmb1NaS8dCeNF0Q4UKHZ9IgIXgiyTMhHr4o1gzvkuUEzFRjZ2M1LhuS1GnZm3@2g2nfE7CK43NqI1wd91YzNImSsYXdVU@OH5a5rcM45nfVeaHA8jObW4Ju2y9rQNLYE4EOxId9C5vvq8gvwwevjclGw5tSmn9LipV/jOzJ9IXdLC@9xHA2F8TQmeze@bkljBO4SRYzPVLJtuH9gTA@jQUYIDGQoed5ViRLMukdk2uguUQUZfvpdFhxuA49R7mUxO37C7PZlszo@aJOWvVNbnnss9To91awQKP1Ir8VU0qnBwyPaGVoXpyhobtqT1Y86NzHzd2YgrSaNtVcqD73/QSyDXdnKckHoz2/CWrmu6@BKPcBth04p0MG08tXouiAMTppZkVQunjtiEQSwzPJ23LAhPNNMtdgLDWkfG8I0WKXKtZwFub4qnVjf0qQ9gaPy0KJ7JjXUS2d1EqZ57ir@N4sMIVFN@Xz@jvV2L1QcwJ8nu2QbM4xung5XFQVx8vKGjnlq@Sbf1hD1ei@i0Z68NXx0C4bJffBnvpm7tW7brs@d0v45AQw@owO/rO3SclpbhSLQYHndfw4PCYxbLBjXsoWsXy0PFgNvGVp95A@T7wfNDOVzEoVT1Bg4Vij@uowbPjXz9WPGOb2ogemfSwyO2Mec1U@w6NhXsvWyuHSgGuHG3vmb3cmXKKSt8qW9DwbjlcmoswudPMXVsIm04dUwWJE6DdIcZKmVwTD0uYv80peWvL63/YUzpCtjSTZWINe6xbcJkRfcrTcq0nPolc6i53IezqIE9M2fmWkXjSfe1iW/3X6NkfDhSuaAa28FKPW4O4NsxUaq3gWb4QVjjPI2@a5mJYVs982ZRZpWpTUD6nqDq/BQcT9FxNcfQmU1WWnVFO3OeXU@y0SQc0m5/BTuM@bJ8qHyDpLQin/sm/a7VmLiGh2fU6oVcLhcIMLEdlxXPdZqUHuV9bfH7SsEUsix5mRZ32byYc30ZRJb4KciNLEjbpNhT4kpFcSzHnC7w/oHctOu69pdpKWCq@M6yC9qqRKd9r2uxK@JO8B4LWy5d@Ljg0R1sWrTgs02gWwJ9UGm@rtHjW0If1JoSbnqOcUNq1Xv98k1sg@mmUvD9WlwT4ud/7c2yZLAaospluXTtqOMSqts1bYM/5sX8dfAqsn4tvFWmEWzW4uYu39JdbsUnLjGlyQKIZfVBSxmZY5O810j5Rh8tdQSPjYnmLv42Rc9Ns6fMD83epgQTC/iCg/eVPeSYsDR1HdCvpnjUEPUUGw@zBqGbOHC467eWyA/GxtDkpmOu45TLBQs8TcPVuqVz/dJFlZ@g6UG2pU2QzV0CBtWxufDD51qAjxY9aNfZ@ObltkuDv4droB8w2jedor06xTojd@SMzBE/uh75Ng0O6I9TburnOtQB6@EIT9NNJiun7OP0tF3b/hB6ImvkjNJ1B2txOsT3b/HlsS8Fl7/sHzxuXLwzppx3oGPjqBmZM5iXfHfqTkyJfJuS2rjQw@@beGi4Sf3TriBdq@cDRcLnTwv/Rt1yaLjTyYQenYk98@lGWSV6bfomuWnAj6bQuUzXG8pv3XFXDgLl4NwKbYGvZzFda9ob4XvrvGebQ7fbG1k3IR3YylDCJR/u/SDdFSljMekuBsu2BeT1FjL2l3o8/jk@Hmxq9GD1iE9rkeMaeWXdCh29GS5NjOOez1dD0cWquCAcG438/fEqvYFffTOzpkugsbNM0fIu35ZAxybcg9MTGyUrek1jyYaDUxUbeykJ6SiQS2YOBB51U7Gr59xiQ0zX@W0TQvFaEkaxcylfhtzB2R9aHbRi67YQvtK/Vg4trZ3knNFs6F9lmHy5vg8iGt42L1vQcerYkjXMWYYTPDaRWbMVfM8Snh2QuWbmtXsqhWs3VSidakuGa8GjAw9outnGNTTbmvj8zqTBxq244CwT6OKX9ws5bRbrlemgYfrmgG@BoOsmEXHsengSGWQQqYc76biCjsycC16ccTnuEJi6ZLNl4jDtJrFl7TGh9c0fzZnS54/NoYFnrR9aUzysuaZXUJddd7zoRthfnxm@9fUZ1GxTZ0OjEXwb0otbF0DfGniPjKHVu7/SEBGSAYGDk578sdL9MehqW5yOLB9PNEWOaxamsMvxToy9rgN6w5qUl9ftI3sZywHE38Rcm3rd2ro7WeALawtyXbesbk1plTV4blIdNx0CuxaJ09l4MvODx3oc6MxUfBV6fEzh/qkFwKU3wFrZyLCn61eqY0uuIIUFk@LSuUka/4Zlu0P2jXKOgdAGQhgK52s6zh2Ynp/igRzPWdMTqewP3PbEhQ7J4xV7A21r4nsVjjW9fjVnOsXDOeETK8NnDnxDQXmId/n2l4UgHa2nyMObZf3l29E3zO/Q8567M69nojMyeRJXC4JSzYPw9DG@0eGiyZbTuJbWc20YXuCw1w6ZnuvMppI3c66dFYrXzgpVNHgV6wYs9fXDRy/S8d5Ap7VvkkJDk2hL18YDA5c6meWAILaZj66mDnWJu9xU0zM6KnxDnn20J9Ujdn3XXafvPF3ABPLBChMw/9n4rtnDbcMby37sPnIdF2ajCTDK8TOTmx1YOeixPiNme4gv1gN9@jcW85zAbpiEuLRhTMwutK@9dH3IXMQB3zWmxoapiNYGSf@LXDf2Fcvumt5rWvSLuTeptKsI3TfnpFts7jB8DErTXo@LxLgetzJGVnZs/InrOvxO3DYHD/XR9VwFpgK6ffhGuYwH8VfWBdbqZ6tVfXLCT4mYfW4XY1NdPbPr2vx@zZkkx@JnAgzPMn3lIZpZoLBinkkgffnX8pDStTxkqRqBJHti@LRJv17VWIJU51/iCNDI8Hou7oQFjmtO58RsI9zApqOz/fzgQBcIPweOZfRmgb3Sm9Cyx90x3TYqDLHWfGZ28a2gLhkUmRrzq43JV4YCawqxE12RDYKQXeGgLrLUU9BG0jdPWyt61CpVrQndiFNv3C6nwzqSY5m9twaumrlEr@Xa9Eo81Fl5TM4Na9WxYUSryIpBL9uvHUmrR9dAoLFNaTryQOdXptctb4eWXtbsh8zGJm4yr@7CbBRdXX9ElXXX76dHzNUzpcDcIPCSyPQglw@l/Y2SJ4KH/yd3PlFgEu4U86H1E2BdN@/gA/IzzwkeH9IDn7r@dGDNnwDe@BbAJnaC1SpAFnjwkYGunU2VgNZzZjZffRjGzl2N@6SOSWQMWpJsYtdTUzKdE4ls0c2v1sjlL30p@2hAeGr2pcAUA@40SA/D97@iZMFzzQZqnDfiYU9V4YSdF/PB8c91xD0NOQPIW@5Umvj0VCb@0wcPnxzJE19dOz/tj/DtiCty3IptB62ciy1JvTa82H4nP47Wt/ypcue5Kh08fCBjgg305jsaEjxwZ27lsXHdMzQkqxgbtSCMNafrBcT7R48eZpavaLLUwchzx2Y6Hn3w/HkW3zT55Pna6HjuezA6Bu58Y/YHh6qaXtN9Xzi0O7iJe64paROkIxO0UeiM97lpmBuFq547MftHi4n5KUyeyMH9Dyy@uLGSj40Ta4ijkFU2EooGKqvIxXw6djIblG3Ti56b2vPYmiC37NFD4Y@Nx1FQctAVT18vPVy3439ZimG54CTCl8uk5q721rgpY8Xw/76Iqaq6ic7PjQG0KytsbKzVBOv2h2335AO2ks1AeZGiIGkKvUqybjxHXpLGwLoVvOHyfBAIzu7GYzDXAYiCi2sH/KnpLAxHor2s68SLKuTGQ23XJvmG@QEbUtEJnxO0l752jy86Us9SPXKmbyj4yItlOTi48@CmDM8CWl6f6uPHL9hTw0c7KNcnjGNsfgDGS8notYTrVmiEb@N2at8DUNq18IaT9eO5yp4bXt91FvObN@HoHVSc2sm@cQQLfZTItK25tW6u6vF1rafrjxndVDZ/icNdrMjBcfs4AaD33/4XqprLkfUjfKo57r2hZcIBzlLoMhZoUi8edfQgYg09lFtkCEiv1UYfmnM8jsJXg9cp9Wvnt@I1c18pvXk6uS6ufE1c/pryrsRhINPlnHoNwMI1cawgR9EPXft05MoHhmf6a84fr0XouopUrqlIJcadA4PttLEYuDeL@PjqQvBY21uPzKmXn4zcrpVfW4f9Adq5ZI/QXvvV@OA4heHR8ZahG7zywf3ryzudmWsLemS8XR9BnOZ4bRQwQXM0o1cirkavbpB2QeY1naHFTTyyO@70kHzXKGbRG8/rzyJYk7uzyWaMgTfiVzEus/OVhJ@Bzuye@uwOvhq3FNPX6P54Pm59@CaZlkULg2jp9P7Rfti7njxXtFiJSyw@f7oSjC@PTp88j4V55ny@SemV5pt0yLUxy1IfH@VXit1tvDxZQ6zN7xuBuAH8OHpulIM4s/vk@VWWgOrbaDq2w5hPDGe5YrrSYH13Sm8aro18upjTMcq1LT3ip9jWxXm9NcErij1MyJYFZftKp4PmmDqdTb3yyPyc9h5ADGJTLpZwoIHhJXOeH4UYUpaNA9U9Xgo/K@g@n4wsZ742arwpD50iTb321w@Dffbcdk/Zw8iq0Cb2oK0HbpyYzibmtO5lRamiXy@F6ZdEqk3twj@gEjw2NcmdTYLaJZ6BByKu4yaY/1lPuRd6PtXSN6b/5HmY/Oa0B7aL6/d9aza@OTGBzWRuTuhdw/4uA7RuTobfGzkeuZ5zc9KwO1Wrd8wPRGLrg1OOFz33A3DoDgY3Jzr03ZsTPZrZUwt1lvVJH7szGy0IrIs79IZrwxu7jVZLrsqbItGguz/y0pvj8VykO/NBB7Ii5hlllF5b05XAsM/Ew9C@vOnIjpu@BPcTl30NLcmvIcXbD2yjT@5tSre6YTPDLX56I3jp3HSod7LQbxzkb60heT5k0DnW@Nq0S5N/DzzX4b70pulxaf5vTUn3Ddu6kaGFBx60G44@4ITG49mJfjPXAgFhU1vwF/xhfoh/n8LPBua9uEEMbobAl8OPiKRSDnSj9OoX2@I2FdCKe2obrRhvk/0ESHt@zrYCmwUQIYZWEAIrDWjs1HJmJppZ4N9xmta3oZh6XS1U2B5@Iq3K1ByViV9@rHCbkmFhTbZ9FlggqFbVC7ZVZ2JVZIENiMhEPDdzDoDRQDNUiknHKtueQsx2aL@A0Rd72DmjZVeph3ZwwScrcUsutcDCA@C0ffb0wdPD50f7Ry@eN3Pti8ACRFgLx4HSQjszH@l9ESof0A3UOf7RA7I8YkNx9DUhXK71w3ox/ELZatXqK1VbVkrcwzzbZ46jKGQEQ5EuAD9J5KVRLAolEMRhhzWmBgrsn1S5PQoyqwFtxEGLVCY0WpXl1hU8MUA12XaC@Msf9KNY/OhjFT/7iAUHduqhJw5dtx@U6Jvs5iss8d7@g4cvnh2yEMFlrzm1@tNRvVLgnzHghnmgnQYWnQqus2SQJQltVa8n7yWBMEk5yapktoQ@IQAdHZKF1EGDJ0HuHZbaJvhAwWTUKMp/@aZykZTxBZc0pE2GSCWhWOjz1FG2trbYEXQSdvfZg08PnzHE//AuBSOJEAQ7QpsJf/bDPv8IT2jTLPzgpTcmPYJsQglxuymhMZGlvROkOY3dyebPXtJHb8iqSPS1nehzYYJAH2OCfntKFlEvmapMk/U4/pnOwJJoWBB1ofDDHbiXilZBkUNZvoU2TRCHARrpXO3sePySbOPKbB@/6YlfDjXoi1CA@syZckN4gTmsBPQ0OeI5WbZNyPLvR4mxhMndLejsXRNUTOY7Fkxy0yp7DT0R9yur3OaNJDWSV7KEoKvkklAtiSW8YtXTV1qe8v6X/5kyrDFwT8H9ncA9z90B3y8GvgG4f4m7XyrY0a5aAV3iEkcIjQcHNeCIRPRH2sc@ZepwO0NLwqGx0pCxMmsMzXRCVMfkvAR@l4AfL@Gkmp9Co0F3gxYL7Avx8kyvnULrxVVFwS6Fyx4yzdXmnB@1vmTFuFgo5lUFkJROQoD02ZEh2pDgANPpKgwT4cSa1F@BKr27u8tEXPs068Uab1ll23mpi68iRLchrQBzIyDXZJAHsixzQFwjyAazT0ZNY1bkXkk1iYyr78K0RPE4faHfCQghshQQi9PIxO9YzPGrt1PQCAJr3F38Tmzsk1TbASBJhTmJXGlRCCzzPHan0H1gkC4/Osct8@CrBnwKRBuzPv8WNBnBxv4oXx1ZS4MS4bevgrEmIw/goPTc5dk03rbiZwjiOYKoiuu6b/Mla01bTlvhfZNBN/3Bms7sgPsXlOGGPsvrvX/V/nDqsvVgJBa7/dxxcZH3HlSGpTRF0xW1mF5WKZ9fW6WgRkExUB00cnYOxQGbApbRM63X7sTfPzh88MmTp8@v2NillMnLyYDvN3YzLUnONtuRIxmv1mqT3LmnPH90517YEEukizFuDIw/qIl6XU2WezcIcvku4OWqrcPwcu02Y/wZtxZyGV9duw41ynQFDzX3Jcql93Gke/RW7eXCtfI6ahUK16G0hKfEQB9wkwhXUE2lzy6abdCwnETyak9YMxBeJuQdHATgavk72wp29quVw4pFX2k/wm9f@vGxqK8fi@K2jiYc0SLL1D1eGrkMAmIRsfqGxQCLFGQlTLpx9D3hQvrSFKvGvyLPbT/GLdvFEC7mrqN4DNRR@EF65CJLQ9KBDeURaD@21RVCi4LclnJo8jUyo8ytAabSQvBFJF5wKvhE/bw6l@nwbSqN3I5gZdl1ZplDeGkBBjRKd09noIU9dSf8Cxl0yOquGbqeucB@7874oqzJPpmNId2AHs9M2vAGzi1BZqBkMkKVy1LAJQKrzPMM2r2G8ppomzmouDzuF1LztDwy531rCLw9lc4CR/tIVdssstyMlSZLzU5SpDZbtsK1Q/FjNHQRJ/uXMt89XyJgNA3ZcvrmPJU8TaarbSgfw5Onn50k0@K6vkRmxAO72v3L9sQj9Evq9ZzEmAajMzTWvY5bVCpXuQSEXQbM7VqGn@erVOSRL9DnVusouT@feg/BCWJEajA2Jiw1c7hNUJmRN9VKOVkylig1uL1hh2UypFDBgyJkRjkH5OLzd8pwFiyl1PGLvBDqO318vLUmrKnKchvcVEiabeNnMw9A4kIruWkBlGDIUiWwdexCoGYARnyQyLyDQx6Mh7TwIMuqa6LpK4K0L@giTajWrHGLxT6Duio5ipVKNWjQVa5YYdD7rrJDWQGwV/hcKNcDdQNzYUAzUH9lIbFk5Fc5XoLKTXBE7gd2xgCdRMxGeGh@jAGspQXv3sjDX@rQgbEC8kG1@uLoXqecVkQW2SsbelYf9635lzYiFS/4NhoMU2UlabLGNbqPMRtahu1wg2hooPQeDRjxEktNxMkQWNcOlWV/2TdV9dpeH2QMWgFS5nECCN7r7oTg0JpvuP6zJm49s//JTxIobKS2VfW4451kkoVcDW5qrcAK7KPtliRtN3P129sGaFHTN/MW6OTKTv7EvDsa9B8MlZYoMp3lFWXn7OwseW/nqfWywIpS39KKb@aLC72ov5lf6Gr5zfFELTblN/O2WK5nj9vs6dPP33XepcX5yeKN2EppiYMn56KaR5U/Ua2ws72injiugPoJ5TJ2zN7CdTxg@E/ut/2Y20B3dwAqbFJkiVYLKK6KJVFRmsk2/JO6/wourvg3G3JD3mu/e5duGsZ0vmCWZU38fh9@7ggkSC39nIG@fAs4Pc@gsBY9SYPCazwfXF1PKDA23zeHw9mh0dDwlX/5dqe2sGb3po@@8Vl4vcDr7bNYtrfBd7ozmZQkNdesU1Q7RiGBX/z@sx9tXWTPnnZ2/@xbY8XcwscTfHzn4hG6n6uFj7a2PrpzJ5/PaprG3U@/8fRn9/f383ezhafNwl5eym3t/umfbG1p2q6mbLV9X20nm8fHn4taLi/Kf/Y7yc7Tp1/3/Yb@f37zXUPFWwluJ6wEfAIunangxHsZfirKWB96Jd4moJeriQX9dRJh@NkWUxt7pf/6vSdvEtNEQ1M@8@A5TbxJFMsJ7gQH@PTQd5JoJHYxWfEisVDq9To4S//130H@xicAB2MWu3BrFEJYxUWiIdUpy3miUQSHqmlQ7v/9zW/GMORsok5iXHjdZk24xHxJE/facO3QtSugHVgppyhhOmc6mpouU8u31FvoscADD8fED2qY01ZCLefZk9uQ8lkzk8m05Y4El/ySFokUVdVaqnoL2IH00U69Lu0wbulW1wu30Fp/mpa0hi7MmOatz1auxGf/INdaMLWfGtwzIVHcuv3qbqMBddIb@k4jQ1cwkGhMlcqi694WWZa9SoIK0my/YrWHGNUQc2VNzGaztzuUdD5HWknzediT8OL3RCIKwSHLLoU1cLS3WRTOc7GreVkc9Np0iUO8/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PuPaCjX6VsDZQcSncCQaMB1u1rtNRpiwxPPWuhvQD/KVcvVstK5aKV2mo32M6bmPj5PFvTkc4bcX8UyWulWk/I3qNhGUDz6G4llcIOHNOJhQQRPTAHwDCjFEqtUI3dENcYupYOpNXilQGqeNNoSCkR1qakWC22J52rehsYRtVJF7LQT0vYCuI3WbmgF7Qm73eAXG237zEVsdK0YViTAt7Gs2zJm6WvEgxKNMFtjmebLpgtwqgiJZlNpmzQfNEJEb29Vt8rVYlVTOo3NV22ZAy9KaprmUz9xkoiuGgv6YUjPRNQzY2Ev4y0RNQsLOzBbyXtDOmir69e6sWkYNZdeVMVa4NI6IqtB/9B0SRt2xJwqRoONesEeXFvwR/9wRV68b1FIEExJrl5brKruaLpS@Kh4qOH8esMVR1mAeYL1ut3u214XpA7D6Bo9Q50aM2NuLIxpd9add6e9WY/xQROwCPz3dLfglt154JWlhF5QtxO3sE66VtHK@JFFvVzWK5peUvVSUS/ltHJBL1f0Ul4vlQCgXtL0SiWvaXqxpBfLerGoFysQrkGaIqTREUKpoFd0IfGuucWecb7WZpnwamVuvF7IcidwksPFnyS584SQ@Ee4Gqqmsh2Y8XJwAzGPnKCF45@qCiwBottZ@91O890ODPlGZpfYbbshBVjCQ@7cbmeki4smuGu14H@3ETlrdHEXVK59kcnsvmyAPPOy0cwAyJcBSFliBFTuNNq7FBMVFpQWRO@2QSKSMrvN3bp7QD@ZxpyUzLvJonu7DYB3V5C9fTsjg@s2AGhswxBPZzLbkrSFs20zmH0gcbuRCWuFOKRA/jg7@yl/oDoC/7jYvWhcNHcvLnZ34X@X7hfBE0Ivdq/802N5bUizjG8j72k1lUZLaQX8pw1@WWlgiKy0wNGAJ6Rr6lq5jTMeSi1y@7/Nfzm7vEchiHJbBqyFxA7bSaAhWD2xIyRevf/if8Ff6/0Xv48SKIM/syokzpBRKDuov1a4Ggs35jxy2CN@OeDGX@jFEAxoPMJAh98c3OJSlFcyq/JdhJRaLqZlnNI77qCDtmVk9gqSrjBV5KJM1MpFsZNRFxpL7IrFErHQn7lyJZPJf/JKq5SSfOkHjaO88n3/UQzLJZ6QuKblVEk9b/Dvf/BPNf3Muuuf/MymS0icV5hZBfqkGCeMkIB@lFAUSWoIicbuGN@ewc0XCfXck/rn0ot9CRdmjCltrfX4okP9wWG9Ummg1mNuP6VBs3N3B@4q/B9uQS1YawBJW4N6bwwSdWugF7QWfisiIXXf4N/Dt/jHjnr49@wN/rGjt/j3bIp/7FEX/47e4N9@F/@Oxvh35w3@PXqLfy@G@Nf6iq6rNXH7jAiTUSvqxfZcJALVEmyv0frK1FtU6cNnorangR4ZLF2l9HwlnWh9xZz3zMm0Gqwx4qtMZm9aM@qVWreuBUmDc9gYI1t@@GX5YEmxqrE0Ln7qlYLrSXhoEG4QkNErquslf/zdb30rWa8npSR9syoPYVIXE3UpEXghZ55jgt8CBvyguX0/Wbud/EqTlhUKlXYTI9sQISTqbFvdVnN2rpdTu2oXHBbLeSw3yo3UvkrqV85kuUVuwXJjV@2Dy4S/HLis3IDlhizn5BxIBrHgmnZyU3QN4DGEvwEA8uDPwvPoXTXXY1CQjaIofZ5X7WDO3HmnJTRZkomvTNCfZVXOyUWrjV8Ua4qvXrWUnbZWKTMZu7Xcab5qJdtiS8SvTGiVPOsuzK3WKxEEjpzIuz@GsITvg1JeSyitlsIJD@Silry46HQOH9/tdBScCFuP3CfL/ydPxnHvtf/jJ@6jJ@7Yhf8nT57A4DUbmdsZmCJu367DlBE89hKN2l6rShNPOPkklN29VkOX0F3MwHyiYVjmS15LiPBsbLWE5CkoRaegT9VSoFWd1k5qtVNyfMa94OigGwOj/9PAETwJQi3SyU7hOiGw5EPn6WetyMUdymenEPQZA10y@gelNe79B/i3/tv6f/SCpVmq2U6nzi52U3Sl8S@dPrs4uwjujXQqFXhSu/CHAeDHLGcXDXRSojNwNVPpdvrigofBPZXe5QAbUMxug/Iu08HElIiKpGL5LfUP@4Sig6uVrDFghLReUMjROEqINWYszwq1WvNcLg18LviADu58G@d0ICNdo6@nbnebavtPf4c@krSXpkSFfK2m7jDu0fJarZYPfaVyrVYOPdupVOXq1cjtqUVQqvL5dLpWA89eCDYHXsjbZO8yrM5acG/fusULKWvn5yFMPV/M5PCMVq0WllSAYk3f6AVM/@zBE/q@ELCaQgI/7MVZSSpHXyfDiSApVsVbt1J9E1966O/tp2/d0iq58/MoZDKBIHUlqNPpW16ng@H6@bnYEelsT6UA/lz5/FzNVTJqMu16qcf46VQoKiWp7COtQaVWgMlr@RJEBwgUdneL@UajmIeQYjmZxnMCnMUDvkkxWRMTZ1QHtVziHFCsYXD8zBOMZR/n2rOLBDUoyxfSKWCkaZBCLxL45yHP5XNdoZAGylyIPKVaqfCkaZYvpsqZSvBX30qzBohZ/A9lRT2T3ynt3AapG//8@boLeXLtzKyrF/Uzs4o7BRc1EBV8F4QktNFj3rqlV4BE5VytJXQ6d/eP9judOsxlKKrBDQOJuwtoushLVmu3qV3VcoFBA/JAKQlTAisDlRVtp6CWkSqCNUCbW0ADgat8W2xL0OiJN6HCSbUFgaBBQWl9uFifddkQLzZEDZRZzKaL2YzH073XixK5/ApiIy/lJSU1DDGjSwiGnc77JMzaTx/uHxweZbVdiSW0e/sHWe35izsJFb2FpZ@idfQ/O9y/@@QFZHj68HD/@eHHDz49fPEUwn12urxCLh/cl8@4a43/lH0mvPbeGqZpmDPT7JzOZqdv2GvL6ljQevYMKuUOPeabHajLxFjWqwa/nuUbr18b3oQu9v4H337/g//u/W9/9/1vf/v9b3//x198/9vw@yH8vsuf3/23lQLef/zFv/jd97/12xD4H@H3R/D70Y@/@LVv8h/5/xh@/zkW9sfBL5aO/wSA9Ys//uJ7v/PjL37p1@H3r4Lfr1/9/fKP1v@@/3Obf5jve797fZrv/jv4/R6HFab97m/xMHxeSf9bPN0v/fr7X/33/P9Pgz90/vb7X/1jvAWef/7rf/qf33/rP2ha@U//zfuf@977n/vW@5/7zvuf@6fa@1/7N2oufvvd99//g7/6w9/7qz/8H@n/h3T/vQ/5f//r//wv/te/@N//4g@D34/g9@/B9aO/@A8wVP72D36A/9/7g7/9ox/g///8r//2D37lb3/xfyLHb3DH//Ov/i2///Uv/6e/@c3v/NWPvvk3v/Kjv/mNP/ir/@OX/q9f@09//d///l//s29h4G/86K/@6Bf/8lvf/suf@5d/@a0vNty/fe39iw8I/@IfIeTD8fwQOB9Sry8b8sVPhc/fhxrLUqCfQO/@hfe/9vPQwX@Vsfff/iG@zgq/Df8/1FRK80Pu@/@AQ7taZ4zJgQt@v/L@299FEv0PQCL4j@j1ncizEsM931l6gKy/uSbTL/z4i3/5O@RLmNUGbT3hZF3WypkdUGh2KpVgwg52pSDLz69CiwAEJX0HOdRK3HeQt73/wTff/84/ff@D33j/g1/E2VrKV7L7WUm9YUsPEhY@IB0mLH5IOkz4OZTfydCqnpT5HHxbnxfKuuM4tc8//1zonCv43vTtc/Y5/LHPw4vxKHyvOogK4zAcX7RmEN589aqN@8CxMEXlwBWNP4MoPKYPJUnaR5k9RdV4lHmubPNcrAYBellvxVBXBoOdKvwxuFWrO2dZaa8FQh9lvRDMsEpqAHVLYaqR1Xd0AxIqeZ6OVZ3buXymtGMYoAJnEG6GZJ6dUAYr6GyeCVe92TxY/Z5jovkOOee0HM7XxOEu4I3@S4yVmc6Yw/9rAsvQQjld@H3Z0EmOIF9QBHcKBSgmE23EUcEobxGGPIQ22ancfIVhDebzzBy0bXBACRmIugNyf72ewYx1jiJ4eWUaZUaoZDJ1qDfm5nmynTKCmN8hKJCznnnGOjv1Oc@YQXiNkBwZAYOeiaomZsr1u1BgfX6XISwETmBfvao3yvV5A8G949TJzDN3CCcEVs/MG@/AXyeYkE9I3H0HqJTrmUyjjAViJXnzZDu8kQpUOap7hmWCNoAnviuxd5uxj0S1LPI9li0kGE@N98wyNSaE5BDfyuwE1aH/0Em/HSL4FhUVlMJ4/B7JxHtcTMYEAFeSZFlm8MPDC3vsNkTPOagMFQuPDIeQoR5BPSAKYLgQlREy1L4Z8kD5ifrOl74QGFZme3tbSDREXXwiE@kUhXnHVXpxBM9Soh5TZWKxImKwSW/RhLhA/hqVv53EXckk44DZRxn@u317h30E1aTnMkxgUkZ3826CQ9nNZEQN4DfcjPAS9B8B@ikBOhfkeZ12QTNCNsuYXE9gHHvy5EmABAW8rAsZ6OaarqIfN@Nms1kCcshyVs5mg6dMTwqQA4dMscFT3kbinnrW1GSalq@BmlZjGMTiOpUKujYGvnv3DlqFDqdVH4CWy4Jzalq@TJEQwM1W2fYifN1Ky1cEvgTA1GKesRStJsOVZvheUQo6UlrgLzVwNMIrldTK5SSlBPrLqZ3w4GJRRQ7AX@Cit5hZobTiBWziXlwW5GvPuBUfvTnF8UuVC@kw8uAJO3jy6NHh46NJu80E/IbtbGp2Jp7bM30/hXH7j@/y91@0SjGdaDaRKkdVDTmScFjNYUfNPLj77MHzKuNUCtosRfWo0S52QJeKKiQmk892E8E5LxE/ROqKz/FeXZIipVWAW6YTDSHRM1EFgs6H//CrCY/84R13zlK5rChm1SKqoGncjQU8ftadMTSTzW1qwSDEt2Lk3V2igNA4k2KbPxjQYM80gTsklRxMr5RDR4k71FIRE/CzlEwXGs8PjwD00ROmajlZaHzO5jKiJl0IDbtum85wOtrGQ4liKyfGar/dzGXxT9N1uKv5YlYtlNpbW/aZhAW1qD@c4enSC/CeSVjhr8LFhK8K7KsQBBeUgUdGWbCW/uBJLTg0iaYrU/zkpKgWYASnBdwP4OCESfyqwcBZ3U4TElvf@MaUNRqHj@9KD@4JCWBEIxaeG5SsvjySqUP0Z55JsUPG@tanFn6LVu5b/sQ2FjAqgRqJi4uLAUB6cI9pDY28PEcf7xc9CumC@2JuCAmnWq2/U/Ml4dl@tfpO1zQBAoQdBQ8mbkFXofMdOwr/q/lQiK6XFWCCqijCQ9d1gTq6UDUFRmd43uXqdYn3Vj2v0hEeAT9vZMzrWnQFaecfLdPqOZ4WYyCCDacey4VxJR4X@IoC@YBoeGoRT6ALtWDc527d0nEhRs/nohUXqjG7gLbZ1vM6UhzfCmsn8qVgq0kUxXZCsM0p69fBnWjBjS8qampCZOhDfqSXc0KimWgK/3@9gl203UlDz6m7ygScBjjzu4oBzi44C7tKF5wWOCu7igXOWUNXc7vKrCEwYZdbu2ZoTKsuTs05GtfnYWLDN@2BjC@J1UUqQBN3g69HNMKMjX697/ZmeD6n1pctxzE9NH3BM@TzYs110A5rPdy8AjaWPhOG9VMy0CGY9aGMpr08x7CFvtx1@wvZny5sfN3Kdr16EkTfZBixhG6CTIQLfnu6nq82WVueuJM9QSuUMk01B5MZ/tRyVstumXulUrUv92zT8PYK1UI528c3uYKtxb1CrjqUP3/08P50Onlm0utde/kKZEBjmGi2bq9cLRTazaYoZppUTLuZa8ucn0lbW8AETKMvwRN3Hn1JK7chc9/y6vVkck9XNUmt6rnyhbAkHNIca9gQMGsGa5ZFup8FLKPquA5wp2rWyFpnRIXqYDC42DnLLD2CcSZxH9DnQjKy3bPIW5Ni6apslpWsZSSEGAMg91mwp1oVtUJZrDVrS3@pKNbaF8Ltsdm3DHyrq5U7u5qrCFycQ01AQS0mXFQ9151Wu@bA9cxlQl0thgk5QlcT5MWLqLhWDks8u1pcMZZofnYVSr4gXkS5QrSEiwugOyc2kD0wZd6g089NtZJvHwLPgu6zG1o5x2SJly@FxM6zT/VGA5r6LF/S8oV8QdOLxUJJgwmqki@CAphTc8VcQdMASr5SrpQuoF8ryrsEfcSUHZyF/b1Kn3FJGVVuh7jZZul3jy37rKxLHI9UunZxkXgnJD569qnWaGzWRVMwn3@qSY26XqiAS0eXpgPCTNA0SdMlXZVUHf9vcGj4/@HpNfjX8A65dE04QuNkj2GeBSnCYQ/RyNHUZUcufuZuyO6YvQ0pDkYGHU0/8Fzf/3ukuWM4xzzqrsUtgkdR9w381qc/tqajDSleTMZo18z0/tEgHI67gCCyQ57gDtw823XXJSixF0831PJR9A0OIAb/CAckf/bg4/tHsefR4f7BfaHI7jx5fPfSoxAkKrCHh/eOIm@Jx4ZZCxGInz18@PCyN3jkn7x4Npi5Hv6Ee09e5Je3KAjffBbycK0mioIJSHBDL8msIIKAUlgohQ5VwPdlboGifitwFopLZw6dn/HXui0/en@Dv@FfFY7Cd70Nhpy2a7IeN1@HKwdkWjbQKtRSRRAmzHFPWSnH@q5tGx5zB4MtCBwZ@N6qibKybWNPxKJPXc/un1p9c0t4hK/IVkDlGBASwn0AMp71yDIKSD9oqBxmNYfhXlzXnplsNmEbA@GBQej0rOEI5uBTN0wgdA2Dwe/LXpDfjF/T6wOmvAwKuxJjX00ugH5ZLojigSjeN6ZGzTNLL3PV6lMP5mLDH5qNwzn0V/YCxo/hLbLlrC5OxXus83JHG@LWju1OULfxJ00Q8UE522v99W/@8O/@5FeGdWAyrdxBroDLUrt7jx7mtYVRdbj8p9TegcY47p43XrJCFfgdyMKMxN1AJJZJjdIq5UK5omvlbLlSzhfUYqGQVbUsqKylCqgWObWsFsuFipot5ysgmuQrEFsAfYYL1EooQSs7VQDr9OxZ39wlTUwegcrFN2TZ25SRZgkj8s@YaEIeUUAteUqGAXasOsyqTM0xvcQAosF6LHHv3kHu3j1RvIMePNBykBPFPnoK5VyudEcUTYo5KKOYJbo8TxltwopT7snl7gDdZxwAfk5FFEfoOSziOqMoWug52L93D8sZoEfD/JDsmMdwjx16SpDMQQ/I@QTgTQQNku3zcvKE6CF6sEiMucdjDiBOFD8O0cGYZzwZB3A/rOn@vig@4J79fYw5oGoXOKJfQ88@XaLogQfGgygOwTH0YCSKYhecOCpEsQeu3sKAsDG48IsbztQQxQUnDxJIFOeU2ugdi2InDMdiPg2wKSB1q@RRea1vk6eCf6KohUhjMj3y6KKYjzx5qNv9@58ao2nfHPJr4fFnD2p6/75uWPPZ4b3uxx93h8Out9g//PgZRh0c3AcRZTHzusNukLHbgcuFXAf3NeN4vLh8Qa0fdDpVw14b9bVOJ284l6I6i46JGEKuN4BZcA2xoHHnAKIO7nduG@s21AlgBxnCGJ5dvO6M4XnH6PKo8KIoes67XbGG3V9RWikBlQjcGcfheAwM1smOjZ7n1tA/r7NcFuWYRbOYa9cogo1BGcjVLjB@kMK7gYtT6bNFc17Ptevzeik4CjdIia25VrDE7NZ4T60UqlvGnqrlM/Mq2iZxB0mWlNQ9llJv7bxlqcfpPQ0UA7G1tyeJTbW9p6nlarH0cmcmiukq3vf0UvVtKpfMMYa3dLPU3isVYjlKpYyhaNVSCcQzoMkUZvkuLgF1UqlT0zhOpxFbWmaAKlBd2YLqadUGqXl2Xud4sUW6Nq@rNW5pnuWuAOvjZ01mvanrcZBDADffy1XxFEZKVCtlERBQlFQ6HTE90PqF5YrNZ18/Oj46@pzkwEawAvLUM5F71QLvx/cP5AdPQh9@kES@h@Kp68kHyLVWYricGgYdgWIi34eZFZS8MAzfAfVcWz6kE4wg44YRoU00OTAOLh/dX4HzfOSe8pLRhEaNLMw6PZPh91qsPjPqDXAZfZYirJiRPqU5vdNo1Dv1MVmZgCqGub7G6GMmSzAPfI57ZNiDsp/he5FBRKeeu6h16/PEHOB06kxSX43d/ist06v18TMtd@p3MHOtA89uzaybnud6IqjYYm2w59Rnjm8MzKemhyZrHjzZBgkDX5ZMDZiZ3matQ0x9gOrLhdTwmLPE7PFsnDKkRje9GoTrgFEAEif19bDSZ/T@bqcuihe1QZ2lXkLSN@D3tlmqL99J7@VrQKc7rJOGoNyrwasB01gxXyP1I4WwYCgRfbDeBkvXG1@DB4d9XK0CNkFDHwNULAwAW32KgNQT66LWq9ssJbE5SxOR8rVhvYnZz/G2K4liW5Ka522hIUmfCQ0Yr7VFwqj7sy594YvluqqWK9bmEKaW8rURNK/xcl7z6pOZZ9Zs8AaLgvxVZaMGRAXaAZi356n3P//N9K5UqPOwGoE6R2GgI3fq85qDNoOhY9T1OkRkmvlcFhR7uJWyMOdrxaxazOrZfFYqYShM@NlCFgJB8QGxI2WnRMbEbG6ek9WsaqrZVO6V1X@Vzh6nQJYhorF0duoeOrMxgxBoKuyb5IUnkCej7digkPVdZuxK1FmBZdSwYkD1EZtY2RGCemYaNuVIpyWm76Ts7RSm2T6aTQ6b7Wr1cD75OkSlpDd7xUwpl3mbTtdSW@m6b74RGjWhgeyFaj3Zgp4brJcyfzZuQiuDSy1p1Wazi1Us5bJ6TofaWZ3z4a7YENvZ3FZRhSa6YMQ2GOcb8SVElHiWYZMOCuS2CU2nVrSaINN6nl7WpIpS2Cnk@JoizylMAvaGlGSplhi@lp9KJktaMplO1nCjZEsMFrqBpxE/SwJ3Td5S90QQxsSqWNEwwZI10pvXuRA7EMcuBJQVWR703TPh4uxityF8RXiO79Puai/xr/Ty0f4T/PsKBFXAW3756MWTF0/uCUyhQ69yJ1Hbqsm1Tg08kty4LSSqjAEnbQU2w5Qtxr7scdrMbuMlf7bwTQ6AK9B3AJqsTcfcTAuVOfYp2qPYY0mog@GNm5qmt5taCeY@4KZhUk1Ta4BFJ4HvisgNaIz5GeC3m2ngq5xfY4uFkZHCFYBb1cYws53TFomTjlis6PydxIaaO2ZbyVs7DMQZiSVOjrca2k4m@bSqZ5J3k3o@cZJqbTcy6iKpsJ2Mthjgbj3u@ipJSKeZOx/pO8kXmWp5mK2qGbxrcK8mmbSVuN3J3k5XfIGahCUuLUns1/eHz/bD04H7B42ytgheQU287IjlUoBiaxtIpmVeruZuwOT7EpfdWwK@aJBMnCVZInkBf0LiNr3mqvHXXFkietEVd8uDPSQ9X2TpRCUd@EqVhJ@KNnC@krydSOI@SdX33yWoS4VvEX7tlQa9OeG4YQDoeLj@BrNtoYBbBAnl1cT/hlbWHz144tz17plCorV1vuXi1g5bHoV853zydcYmQOAka9UT83o@OLWvNhqSuquhYb8Sq8KEMlCLUu68wYdMgyKKGsS8//lfz893QQtiWk4Fv6YVMlqjoe5oULHJ@y9@H000nR1@uv@QJXGZ/@/@5He00t/9yb@mw33JC1r61/RSAlKiUy2WEmdnk7OzC7h4XCHRTlw509AG@iiqUSntyFAbpWyAo6MkOB1BhCqp6YQvJYITnMWClEqpipbe0cu5NMScBybYUlquDN5wn4yCxGJBTCcOn1kFTb29uwc129PzWm0L2lKNXllm0d@u6VdQo3z06pwx8PQa/eHQ0silKKz6Ttp9x6Rd9g63qN5JW@xVvYFnMlR80TncmNnBVylx3zPZyCg7SQaqF2s0L2oX7Qzt7JDm@nLHaV2iQ2sL39NZDdpx4M/c8enPNMlLAT54Q5@589oXUztpRen3xavrdLsmKzSgq@woy9ex2U64X8P/JKmVfv/zv6Zpxb/7k18@75x3PtdAfa1UiqqW@MlPdmfOzDf7jZ8AgGsM84QqKEmhaEEHHZHqyriFYivIFTnkHmjNMwfFdJ4@VGRRdWUg4lhDx@yTIiucoFhGLdvhtiH7KUq2g3Y7siTmky22dE0QQnmYi/HesJclGGwHzWo322nhTPgqRsGsz0AVqAlfXYKCgDHM826v49szb0LvOaUon9rOsluQBUr4Ktrd3CJ7I8GUIQHvVHauZuUo@0Q1EuHY2PR9tOIJs53wVcgSfHvAXrCJgaZxMKXlwBwlYxLCkyL6TSi7DWXbPEOHQlNUe54gyzh2PJMDor7wVZBaiAoWCDPM2oUENWArXwUCQB1SAWCrzXaZnmZnViZTW5oIvcD3IfC9HyM0yyFgNoTWRzMwYeYapoMgUDHwa9fYL4IWBlkyFhgC4TD4qYY6KCmYnXwoH5LdnA8GBbDIRl2KqsZu3VpiVa9b/TSjGiH8Y2uC627UDs56XAFYqOB91K@KWYbGV2thaNTtgOIZQhd6ncStrtZiWZmI3gtBgP8P7rTYIy81FUXUsAJBe/FR0QOSQWYkO2/DHtutM1UrpVmEfA9w7xFSZBwh0lpb849k7fMw8gIw/Eki/JYcMK2j@Fpm0G8v22VhINPP8ENeaJ2PM4PAngq3v4fM78E0zB3lgqpYNqUeWB7oU3TcIjT9mdLVNGZbmkolPOiNBS3P8MWBQhoflAtTM3gaaMIyKGeLTG/1XGhQf@I6ZPOSbHLhWxvQI4BHBeYCOdoz5xQ//Bi0DWWOY@STqUDs@Ygx2fB00bgR5cXjC10P9O6QNllmDmXWG/eZVmEp6mhk1tCJwKUpEyHcBbEcady1zTGg9Nw06W1Dv6ooQxDVZl2y7fjIgn41umfBDOT4yl1OYOXUOraUI7TALrkDfCmRW8pJoHSHw4@ffwjsKNque8xs69jkS9SpFTtDPgPFBGTrLFB2@QPCVvHMjqZncX1EzfJU8CvBo8Sd5Wws71Zqkb761NWtVAdb9JzmGwtaxTZPDCdGX7rOhUAj9xd@aKmM7G2BX45YrhnYKKon0fpIZHxLCGyu1cncl4xbH5OUmBBDW2XoFCaeecJQtxZwjgGm2Qut/uAohtp@lSYAGnswstCE6dSroq0qwMTrp3ow9AIG77CPmK4JmJAbkguMvgEMbPr6KnSIg6xYD3/ah4aRab0f@QqMznEf4tBKStD9MH/Yu9FN5mWX3ZttBeBw0qGy6owPi9BTiHlwdGB/pqpvQWQRMFyDyVZKzADYjJgWOego/@XsvLcLxEuq7CqkLEMIAakBCokKBrIctFEZ@0KjABF3DJ9/xicwcHp6eiqT1d2ZZ8mmj18t9F3HsJXJ0AKJ2FWm5ngSfB/e6imTEO7SJfGPlcqT0WRvjnJtvXJrwZ@CMPDrwUGmVHLgJ3FyPMGP8g3HZKEPTeP51KHuWfRBz14qOFfF@5/Wzp6F/a@K/U8qJy8QCGMIZp5dZHtZAJbt9o6zg9N@LYg4oQEJwKEVzTAQbWF7oWfshy5rMohSuFPko1FU1z6mDWSAJPKF5GXRvIZhykXoDfwTaw6ZHPOU7XuesUhRfBpTYwdOLUjsYQuY9ikGnPiJgzNumNmaNxftlezzKDtMatHxCQ/N7wln1wPlVroxfs7j5xA/5/HzZaFhsc15m4tkGHSB1cFej1Zbw5QIZhGmueAWrZcxBBnkcaZyEJhysRJ2Ab9enXKH9OY@aMd62DGgT0yA4GZKab5sNVttxzdPd9oZZQidXSRCQIsD6GabaHraj9xIffvEnrj@SpCDxnphVgrwxqDeKOgNvK9gHaMGoo7B6WWhfdXhODjnwQWCoMIAAeUwiETRYH@astK1yCw8RULHaYpLGnPEmgEybZK@gqggDMQlTnpO2DigdgwQhkdVAjQhhoUjh3@jNuQOn3kupAnTSvRZzTHa@Uu2k0DJS0OF85oaNVIMK0kK0QSyo7hav1yVMB6aonkpKlbNi6D94@hvfWn0BzAu1mNPHZZPGDUhPlTw1CaIEMFwIaqyRj3WroCBsmPYpgcz1yGXT4PZGorZUUI1g5eDVfBPrWlvlIo1fi/N24feWhUdsRp1hUW9DlVc1Pmw5OMiJCkneJTND7Itwo4Q5OcMBGDk1mYzg2zzeLZ5vc4ZB5tvyHYaQ3JOSM55Fp56vgHJdpANtKcH4fSCzdMG6RSPlYoAT@XTKIhBE5H5xomJu/Gv0QYpbl4EZS55DvWCoA@hiI39rNdeW3ozhnSMaV0CgB3xCoA@/9x9VbjM8FQp8kU8ipMy5FHcF3QDziuggxELrnE73f9vd9@33jaO7HltPgUiO20ypv45iZPIkTuyLSeaTuwc20km67jVtETZ7MiSWpT/qJPMd3Yv9gV27/cR9lXOO5yrfYrZ@lUBJCjJstM958x@2zOxSAIoFAqFQgEoVLkJk/EamBT@3ArPAzR2cytHTq7MG9D4X0n@5Xzz0fwrT38sZXOWsx9L/sT//kM@HoOy1gC1tI9y6REEMlYy73rawa2tcyyq2gUtcEirO7nqK3eGsk3fixe6aPGk2z8pngewqkEQbPlaGIw9s37AEY56MeiPglH/0aOKLJoiZrtZ9cuaITrt9RE7z/LVT7peux/GveURdWqrf9qL4tBXcKP6OdTLjlBHD3FsPVk/9mPH0fZdsowFaOErqLrNZtSLRs2mC7NJr5KYl7MVJdhzednB@peerPIknjTQvYHbP/k1bI2822Ei8IQudhi1Prt7A50IVx01RTKsRfo/pZ6RBqPifrpyZKf2UKVPRi5HTDnrn/dPSeu7iAvYh3UmwDdS2EAoGAwYF18FWNJWrPAjPErclh94uuhP311U/bTqBl5SfjULIEMMXw0naQzKDmdU17yxOilm6jv4fnwPbHwP5uPLq/BJnGVpXpXE76v6oZtCoIwpGg9vRwNNJ7nVnkIng0ryGXqVFLgzim22WmsD0xplrenshQ7xh5@8xfSWIP7@JvrP70BTvH7X7gto2KuDMcmbcxiAipud2JzEupS94UH2TFeXsPb2HeuivIg0vQMVgtRYFlw9@OOmgYnYVHGygWwA38LzMBSb4nu2HqtK4gychpe@@rx6cxdtN9thNxiHbVfn9C24psX7tGBjeXW3hkPQsdDry1rPpbnLS1JpGgfRJVPlBpYJ/EvPu5mtJEuUcA/vlDOGjZvph/Qp0YwtvqrsVtM6YHl5EduxlxG2PxGTS0I@dCXWpZajMv9IT8Lzxu0EITrI7Fn202q9eeJz302adIcZIclbyDYZHtkNRPjUmu7D7yPR7S2lzrUKVU0vO9lgR7N7PJrX4xZXGJ6UY6e7seRtTHdnnrNYTYClImzr@6aQKcgwH2m1XBuifJnbY/3elEzAN96n690wqzRnCNSkJEu6UcTLbdYvPAcr4wb9YsPpPf0C4Gk4agpDmbZhT0uHj1acch4MLK1FfyElnaBYVBSSazSsXI55puxfviV1tm6sszVVZytTZzICslVamZxWpkrdC@ieeV3QDTujG6QzkrB2pp95Ypv@6/WDIXYrvixHy5XIV8uXyxUSyMvhcqXuklBebi9XtvkhXq4c8MPn5cpP9JCOreWvyxUzLJBhSK/88ALftQjHe2u5suV635xR8DmMTb2F5UrSp5TnR3llihAp0G7SGnHE1uvrZo6GIU1srFT6ChwT@1g@8T6Mz/9K9H8JX8aBjZCIPc4HnFmtqHJm0rBmDKmHpg0TOGPGSK7o2by@t8PmV0kWVLNCazy7DIMnNXxxOSuMBDGk8okG/RKCkJuV2Rgpaya7Izq6duJQ7uRs/RITkvWBtsvpR5T5OK2EY9bp8qa/siCkA@@GJwrfhOcUOqY6xghnst4MtEDUX5bnNAp9ncVF977dQ7zXnc1E2OZNFuklBmvJdNLh@HCOo2r2B1km4VTY/kd2Gd6Uk0EJ7p0oxlJBj8wbkvmzbhkEgz34vXnNscoBtYwIQuJR6VhGWTIvsCxGUirrLE1VBh@hYMkcGuFh6zPHA9zWj5xPxI3Pc8VN05ApK1Wy5MqKSSpcgCexi2AktSeL1zr8i33f8tWUvMZeiwsAVsmkFpGv/e/Q3/uivxuF2hBhooJZivXsqXRavZ47y05g3k2rne5AJPpq25upHCU1pCSn1YGlmc/jtSkVHyYfouRLpQn0CW3fkC1ZE9xCt8m1hcCCljC8zH78vEofP6/eTKhpjaR7WTBKSwE1aTjS8ATTtGnzcZWGz@pipPD@dtD97g4eZjvY7jzA4wYMJ0guo3x40WMrl3Rsk9iWLxCp5YoSQc7HpUk3px9J3PPRbXJsSx/2mvvbe7uvP9Kk@@TJE0/P0eMUP4xa7LUm87hAZlvuZD6YsWxZ9RG0C4fd2I6Pz/rD0b1PvdyULBFhTcpAQLUY9tNj3NOyzJLnE2OXyklei6Ia1ud0GAQZqQRVJ8CUHWm6jogg4ch9EGggRr0levu8WvM4PFWz2QvOw2aTp69mE8ZLzaaexdA15kTc@/viveJFPOQQ7xJb7cpx2NOG2t5TH17VDtXhq7raebf1k/q49059qO0ewhPC23ebrxtbiv7Vdw/qysmY4iEOJRaURNftsBUiurBaLZUeKYa81R@MRe64W558PwjO1at@K8Qx1fM4OH9xJi@FXjjakFJ1Wo6OsYcZcdzR82gEewsOlEnLWCg3bb6viMsHivKe0Jr2HGve83476kSU18HadxCFsbniproR9SDJW3PL2xclCTEx2XSIY93CAuuKigeUH2c3BCYQ@yuQGDkkiGa7oDThkv@@m4KH9f03BwruN7b2drcbh4293QO1s7dPr28/NnZfEj0bB4f7jc13SOKMb/a2GzuNrRp/EARKBQW/GL9exKO5KBSQnanS@oyT78KAuj95y@56Q4NXVwHf3IzV8kUP0icKutHvYXt53bmIob7gtigfFSh3qbb/8j3N@Sr8DSec5iiY7Q9y72KO07pUUs@5NhosGzTe1vVwpWkvX/b4POJ8rBCqKVxnLxguP/vKAGcjnnYUqtwWbFSw9y3OMngsG9BU0T2CDVDGYKWqOMTa8rL/nEFuUG2tbh/eWaU2MSLULyj6wpiarDtMMW0rA6C4XtHoYT@ovJ58IL6nD6u62tFQMqiHyQfJoB7JB6iiDdiOqMc6x8Vo7wLiWa3Jh1/PBzt8LKyeJB82A17FPtU4Sb9xlwYqCVEJ1yFdDqQnuzwc7Fd8xqBIzPkRZK7blYERSnhTkolylMi2bZQzR8Kmg6MGbfYmYcORStwAO6GgM4qVW/UK6hDGQWEvkhCGp92gJyZQqekO8556CgdQVX0xPEpC//GFlUGfGRBhR7N4JOW2tVYY3rUcldycqjHQNpIcfteYoN2GwOYUAn8EDAHKZ1Y6LZ6p@DItwPQ7mpXduE8ciX3bv9n5iZ3bF60wU0Bbbbm/Rr//7mki@5l1krFTZOyoi34Ph6RW8lFmpz@kMc5ilYOlQQq2zvqDUSR96GZbwCdOPM1RbkxsVNsv1Y1MbaDDZI29fs@q9IS4@IZaT4gp71Irc7ycnSfiK42iTZxPk7DY3QGd4KR/GVpnZz4Oka5CbL@QIsxn5dj8HI8YE9E/nVR2/E0h@O7T6sb25qf8337xEYFXxIIEwDZGh/hHjIm6aHjwOR8bLA6hd@mRZiInxhcnKK1t8LS0xCg3wGgdeBbRuu5Fcz1JE3Pj6e@4zDP5nT9@/VqVUnlIJh01PT5zU@nmqyNTpc9ljpU2AbFkJyFLst41X3yGmcjrF7jAg16A26Ee5AjW7RNxCbUIMa07ueiQZNHhoXV3J/A9tcEWFUaRFI8Rdn8Uf3Y3qysbXjE1KFEWOV0jon0Duex5llkKz1dT4LbngyP5fXdwT@diJ9PDd0Hbngvtu3DLr9wMS6YlC9bdwf5tDliZ3P4QWGq7fzNgmSSnoSWcnjCnv7SYWNPOr/GXqb7jsUdgMPdiByUBatV20eMjauPr3JUCng0mVYgODrfr@/sqJ@sTKktyD0uGthaDgH1PvU2tbaMeC7tCojQli@VEeTJfMhZt5r95g3km8W4QFVoH8TU9EmGRelTvRNci9fTMwioEW9@zQDSUy2L3xcig@EgD/kZrQEI27TSrgc7MZi7K5BPFthG4ppsvurFtw88W1jJ3I@jycGwDsm2CglPcLJndfx9EP66YekTBguslNLhNmjTNN7ROOKCKB5SxUMj24JxuMV0KI3tRsBcN7WD4Vcpq2H@eoZiRRAkXXdgS61o51qiJfrxk1Bw2SMQ0EMDSUyeKRTMlGBHPX57bHeqlk56bnYJIyUQY3hc2V1Dx4296CmNqJPNkNVHI7bG2xNgcGSyPsTurYa/fnOk@bKHXJsXDZFUkbedWlf/HVCWzRKYmQ/OZjTGJBHnt8eOHt8GebIUpnv@zsGUOmZSfo/MBre9TkPE45u194tzGrm/SUwaYQzoxrTcDZqIgqToz5pRM23kysvEjXGRfiJBBvABENp6s1VPXE7jNhi4zkg2ds0y1wRrCSUNl1ExR/9v86iCQb63v3vfXJ4MNmWA6@A1W@W/6wzhMb@VZHmWsT7iJn/0WDoc9zib3mc4BxeVrTHMv2/FtOzF4lVYhkc/b7JZ09O0kMbv1zV4DV8LbiwUEM8fu3vrk9l6@vG43dafxuq4esLPNTmYvMjfMeZbsuRf15iHAMpj3JTB98B2@@3GF/hEOvgFJZOLbfC7TxrsVN6YIac1HHEFKm4Vq2Vqe7P1O3Ap68EHi5@7HKuf/QAV5F7a@t@PN2lkvrWfKE3LxoOdSKT@XL@S4KH3Dhi4gZUFIb@K7NWHhpoaxlMT1mtM@7KNwsBVey@4ZW04GxfLT0tozh1vX80f@@dGzY/9Bq5pTNPkGvfP4YnjV/nzaP7vsqK4a/Hpy3Rr//ptSjx/B2bZa/UGcKZfXqkV2R/tEwQ/3sxJzrkbwR3YMjeDaBYk6rNSyStfh6/eUxw@8aK7ghsQEl6oH54YLccVuVD0/Wjuu9qql9fOj3vE6LvmNVqqjlfKKiw8/0CxKMkZO5o9Gx5hT7V3XsHep4FeUo9vqqyGKr4bQlzfBMOq/ru2@zOzGQQHAFpi29eYNdQlkvgBrNtw9KfTCK1dvk/kKHOtAQXIW@FZQGZfeeT8Z2zHtiDCjXvFJm42v@e/YcxZKhYvBqM8pxikkWEt9jb46C@YaU4l3FCjLUWRcR@J@AcFJ87g4GJKvY7GizpdFXSvj7qRngThCSRaHuU@5HO4UAlF9l@vo2IkLYdA6AxJdUqu/cjH1/LnCG7FaXOBdPJhyBEO@MFE6xiMOQOhnwKcNqII195ivfTjUfLyX8SBfeI9qxPdk2EDeYU0RKTD/Vl/4fhOXf04EEMIviM5V0FucWvMiRVLuDvLmAjyuZRf@OGbAtUrplAU0FrClvmoKnC3FmUaoVpOJvi9cgZxCK/pPtyBf5repZiT5PcnOJOFzav0Wg5bcpZy0gZ9uWsy1iuVNMZPZIsXCrdTAThctj96ENKzGaivsdglpocVCSg488v1eXf9KUn98hDqPE@QlPT@Vns@kFyRdkEpzFWiCTzNV7Ey5xS9pvm8ql2bzp@qqKlZeCtTTrQKpJGne9Xl548Ko34zSzBtJVwpXJgnPMwl5K@XnGb0vKfcyZRIGT9KPJF3z96ru@QTLTN4X2frx6@gOCtl4VtuaTHBpoRd1f3R00HedAjbLETWVkuIcelOZQVXVdzC1OCENDvv8PGw3qimUlbKRODxmchvPX@QKWsn40Z1EQ24xTg2sGWPEohLXucKEu@YLi1QPJ9@zQDBMMJoyI3fDFB7rwmMLLHLdM9XKLcipAU5NmxziVdyL/Io/ZrBnkTP5FmcnLgjm19J4ud2cJRAL3Xu52WTKShNcF5GPulFzZpG07vEkxNlCYtfaBU7qDOUOdgfb4PcSOWELCiMppuiepGhKpxnKhn1v6kIkfnP@XnzgvAxIxx50w2tVwzIj4FtYTuaC@yiMRzG8ULGDnPhiMOji1JEVviu@Qq3jA6w@xnFLCtGa2QtOA5Y9kt/Hk76QToUKag@Qr2AgkibEF6enuEyGG7D9K4hW7LhEo4JT641lQ4PGzMNVuWYeKjjfYAHcjU5tJKTnZPSA0vEgaIUFh3S0mLQfR5raiXTEWt5Px70RODujKa3iOP9yEbU@b73Eee6Tculh2SLZpT4OLhUePkovWBGRTMIq/BU@Lj9yHOtsuCVnw3kA9NVrTPTviTfDy7DXC50azRicMSalNQ6Hl2G74Dj7YXIIDLhgZZxM4h52/2LYks0dUroCYkbcEo59OQ4jDsMv5mc5Lm7xWZnv4NAqPW2mrr6M2iCguXHS6eN0mA8s4CZA6IFC5@GIiPLAU1mU@OxZ48K6yzk2ooga8HNinU0kZOj1R1GLeoZ3spwugZJjkLSyXnsCE6qv1Q1wObgwCwFcj0kpYBAwR0nzcHD0ofl34aB0w8wZe2B6pkjSr89jhYZ7OIxI@qYE5l7hYhbu1MGHrxoH6mBv5/BDbb@u6Pnt/t77xnZ9W21@5DNuHJSzO2D1au81SZfkNF1OzffoQ652QCVznODUdj@q@l/f7tcPDtTevmq8efu6QdAI/H5t97BRP/BVY3fr9bttPn0nCGp371C9brxpHFK2wz2fazXFnLSc2ttRb@r7W6/otbbZeN04/Mg17jQOd1EZTvVr6m1t/7Cx9e51bV@9fbf/du@grtAwZ7txsPW61nhT3y5Q/VSnqr@v7x6qg1e1168nGrr3Ybe@r9hIwGrlZp2wrG3SEhY1cTu3G/v1rUM0KH3aIuIRgq99dfC2vtXAQ/2vdWpObf@jr4Ee1P/lHWWiRLVde1N7SY1z3FuoQv2y9W6/DvdJoMTBu82Dw8bhu8O6erm3t820Pqjvv29s1Q/WlfN674AJ9u6g7isEs@SqCQZRi9LpefPdQYPp1tg9pDnj3VvYO3jUyR@IMIRljYpuM4FhBoHWEpH29j8CKujAHeCrD6/q9H0fNGVq1UAFWFRsHdrZqEIi4qHdTLVbf/m68bK@u1VH8h7AfGgc1D3qsMYBMjRgkPGRWIcqfcetRj8RXvJIzOoYzvW5O1VjR9W23zeAuc5NHHDQ0NzCZNt6pWlegGdgaxMl6mPPIDi3N1Y6058uQ/jCnN6Rmb1Hk3hM2trbrtOMrJ1d5dKEdzTrPJ1wpWSn0UyTJNJrxmVNOzy5OG1GvU4fd0yTYrLxcR6f@oic5CGKzCdnTuAyvb/CBRYXm833tSYtdA@aTc@/S8kMGreV0Nvg83J5uo0IBYGVNzZ@KhWh@/MMoTZ@0AedbKiHAwjkFOr/IKZvwXnoqWKxHepiuLwPwGbrKJZjkzMcpZBo5MuOCH@TVsk7E/weaXbggq4BX2g1sU8Ky0jO1I/pT@9r@iKTg/WBpLNsdxWLWMQyGtHvoalGKmGXCPxHeySIOlxlIQ7Dz6duya4Oa/7Cab/fdj3PlOG8I1oHnrreLcVPwtOJ4vnJ8owsHzvrKAqxWXezCpOcP2uSKd0vhSG3zMWf5oh/PION@HzArilXxZvVetPS/UGKwyLJV9q1Ba5XcCdD53tT@2vjA1ZzpdVH6xPfXyXfZWzBXhBec2nCO@Jyx/zz6lgy0ABjXxxEkkh7yCgWrTLG3iTJfEUZz5DpKmrD8ofm6rOQ53UiCSmyF0HXrhOz8TC6trEnOfxyv/Zm893ODolOYPvo6eMna@tO4nbrr778fkQ97NiWvY4NaB4nPY2TrFGyRYoPjxTLr3jK/szAxSIywo286TT@CD8Pid1G1pIJggzNjRELqgcTvVwIOuQUO@C45xh@nTkyNQO4maZ6aM15cM0qfkC6EvOANmbpjrnXrvEHsJPhb4Z40iDNQJrF2NUvcS6tLlju5XaMqSgvbthxD7IUcoaPxY1bQgPe6mL7Wdyu5TfN21YvxmLKiPHK3c4lCYl7k1goY1fRk5H9lv2M6A1g9h5GX/6q@Y0eP2oHd@zuLohHtdEBkXEnKYl96nQzWjf6SEM@RlgPOFUzNT1X2OX3NFI89vR2cuIYxBoNjApi1MDGNwt4PfEjMlklW8C@WPbUF@FUOO8AnHXNsfqdOHdWczSUdeM/RL8brxRKYCVOToRqV0kdjsnyMfFjYciZIdOfogfD/yfSZAb857TiJOgptSwngHeiJEMVWtHylYkSXZmDBut0I6Wm/eljCuab3TFnScP06c213K8hEujeGZsPH9ntYcedQQAwOTY27PGbmKSdBbR0epHzdHGck/Ra5wNX6bnCTBVTcPNrxz6rXb45W8GLpzzZa7IqfE1F1QtZuJ3wqKcl08RSXt2PcwLOM/4/ig94AyQZ8MylZ2K1OslZJT3KjBzQrpasCaedeEwitfTbjad2D5TlIjMj@/XJlyEUgd4APtPt5PgmfSXmuVmPizwTq0P2ggf35VgmY/LRLutO2BCzGwLO/TZvhiAEyugKE0RXoLOrvhSacu@zoQgqSa0OUz@DELdegUjL0@pVgj3vTIJDE@zf9cRzfii7WiZHQRx8aAzt6/IF9SYYE8rduzVbWKz44KDvw3YRlcm2hC6PcC@tfn9IqmOAdhOOfjT2CuqD3nQIe/HFUPsvpPksGuodCaP0UzVQm2T1ztOMuKxn1OJohNsK7QLzBzfpPISFqLgnuc6vKZeY1/Dohtl0jK5Xysp9nqY8J5qwW1Im4nO1pr5@lVxCUO0yNGQKRnGyuGCbTa4H5w7J8LvqDz9j7ocK1GuH7cQzqQWS9wKlkxo99vHYGknTB/2YdzSoK7ADklCiLBtpiaEqzdFPNDtpu6Zc6h0Tvku5Jd9fT8KkxlqKKkoZV9dOzLeWp84ElVa1a9DEWWh59TGjMmvB9e3GxRh7C80eW6vcp14iUiqiRFTvG9URTyI3k6ePeNKb/NX7MUYPfcEZt1ZBgTB0VpyrTss5xg82BR@icNi290RJk2kHA2y/8dKn32NeNFuH2u1fKxjF4ZhWAK1idF1kGE33L/2zXnOr3w1Oo34U0DoN/uavReLhccyP6LDTYf8q5khGEpbRytQep8/iX0bcsOE9OZdct1xzxaNw4NpmCqPhuHYmbiJ45xxGgGmAVubvwaSPtKTMo8dpISd7/5Tt8cre@o1lH5ZnFZYTfQDQAm5jwoJC7pCO@GKSdfl0fSrDybwMFo4nKq8C7waLvQzGz4hEfAyTwdggM2WWYDcCK7MbMT5qX/tt9kE4hKOlcDtEAJ7Y5c9@gCDZJEV@hKVARZWflqyicopyDT@EeBjfTO7VJ/9k7AmBP4F@@eEsbpnFCCziOsbbUizrFe1llHBh88CIZTRLYpJi0WnUs64fcrSL60mo2eTxTdRgyx9SirSbvSmuxIh0aeGDgHtuk0ROc@xhUllWyx777YAKUhu5pZsZNrzNfpYHPw5xZecMgmlLQ3YtpG8iVYuohFjBE@a1NsriU/n2EbO6etdemyBgdZbJmRUO280ZzYVvoEQyv@JYqz8kYZyboJ429ViOR/3B8h2pd6PsmOmZbRatW553qyGwMFuVJssHbSZtdYzH8bozic8E02QpxpZmxENYvvJzwuaTRLyuNjHeqs3xLXS4iWap3VQyqST93Zaxj0nxEha9ZqJJhhTjDiel68n3oyY1vHmzBNEwZXnVZInRhMhojuXRAjVBpoRKd6cQc5/GfYIebaIc6m0T7ez@uZGok0ZyxuWpSco4uQQ94bgdlzZJLg06ML6AmzjRcBMhlSic1/6Yj/LK@RM4GUaCAIRWHObTfSjZwU07a4KPODpAx23CWqgMSURPG7aFQ@L0PyEYe@XXmzva4qE5zpeP1wXSdQKJVhWcax4kc9@cXo@a1wxlihQ0xGeQImnRlGw6u3ur/mxbKB9BkNKcrC19Sz4a46kVwob@2EnNa@jAaVW6ZGZEZQdCk0UDjQVapZx2Q1muQvuLhsLxsG7Qw4gWEPLZxc@KLgF33mulhNooct0eI4unyS2jzVP5DSmSMpS8g/x6KIqqywtXAhAKxlS@WiYIcGvK2ONQgF3v2JyXQVT3ERWsljEs6SN7RU3tPGekg6g6w6PHVo7SrBzPbBj5mUBIsZidJ0WEdJbZWVIoNNHNxMXK8WR2e9IcpBAb3heKU1foXsnSMOk5ISDHvC55qUQ5Kiu/pDmYEx899jKJCX9z6rOSlVqaTCX6JBge5cuTqU9LmdRMtaur2aKZkkQPz641k0ik8GyEE6nw5/7jqym2y/PEJtRaZGS0DG2fjZjktMqkdVvh11g950vZRscw8Oyb4Wb51ZQQKxmn7PMdsKtlPjKA7/Y/3VpjmWow0bEC2C@dueziyoKQNdYcpno0Cytd42kvcVBg1rT9jnp/uLOTcft6MjaGRufh8HGpVAITn9jO741tNbaSon4xm7vYueh2i4OrvwzfnxRZ9ochhwSomBV0SF1CgyIu9IenEhkCOFBW5M7ri6xY6190OnYIBpxQovOo2ySn9oageAKKEqOX94e8AcQg9QT7CxqI9v2iktF3FYiiqaGYYygqDZPgy5w5PSPy4EMH9tnJSRUDg2A21kw0b3nVjS@YQRDZhDuL3Rd7X1Lz5NyrsNvt@@oDYiHDU8DCt8kCOzt2gZJkwQkj3@69iNkfra/Cy6hr3StGFpvXAc5MTCbOhPELD9/4@@Fp/Xrg5o5@ztG0Qk1eQTNX4J/aV7nTnKedxd8BrPAhoX2n3OfBwG0xnSYz01SvR3D6RBg9LPsz1z6ZLB7viWma3Z4bRJ2NboGdNVDTPdYFjC977l5uyQ3ZE@LmPl2XO6BhSWBonOBz5W4lcNXsnycWL0edzt2kIocBkI79LokokVD@nEDkMwAegXr4ET3hRfunPA3rnQmHIqLgIFjHtNxBgSYKOM79VvW3K7dWq6mlwcqKqtU26SGfV7XNmtrGh81NtU3vm3j/obr6@PG6yNxt7wt93DQfv6lNgsE7nCuts@E2vVJaFffGYK2NLl4qVpf89aVm9fnGelw8qm3iWj89/ft//e///t/@R7GmX/4XXjb55ejnJFOhUCgutb4s/fBtHe9H28fLSydHS4Pj5dN1cNnf2Wt4vzHKB6n5aGF44izKLGB9ZTtSs85m7zO6qDIx/c6D4WeSLhW12IqLi/prLJGjWMYutkLre4h7lCe0hDdBByaX8oTEIgEdYzueeqcVwgCP5huiJOECO1ApL2crZuMe7mCSDMmpyqL2xMM662WIOy2pJwXcxaUZKx/14rCHHfBL1nmleY4T0G80amr@Lf78Jj7d7F@rB59c9aCkHvjqQS7HP@W1Z/TVWypGuJ0r2Wg5kMv5lJIeLcDMUMURK3q8fuBYOxPkdpwlDtkDSMZNBWeWW3B@svrjyzIScC0@dRYQ81PJFgkfMqHI4pel3jfqli@U41suc9WGFYWmXsVwZdaJStK/UIGCWAwB0prPhSCVPlWJkz6@kYynovmi@9rhaEIMGGTdf7nD4x4faC5a6mmb58xaCmGO2HxevmJuXJfL0Iw2UqT@FAE@UJHlZIlvEi4vLjti5W21kpspt7Dt9mnmE1uHcTgytulS6G/KYgKx5rYJt9TT91q0Ibccr6hclByvWFXlJm2/lWMVOb/ojqKBvq7AtWNAfUlq@yYjCT3KgASO@OyvTI8w3igwnqImukWCZY1Vu4@my0jo6avp1MFeQU6OLCIUf3ZpbH@dGNtekW@JGHYQHmCkElO@ThB1Y@11ZcjEPg2GJ4gOGHQ4oNpIzs14Pw@xWycw7ncSpAsMmU3O0/FMTVkcDIPT88BXi7v9w2EwbtC0RZrPqFXwqIVwwQQkMPh01bOaZxCWFukuYYokTWHLIQQv6I51eDTp21xy5wRdaoaCdruCQZBhJ6Zk@DXTVxN0TLn6OzrBRnlKeCenkVrEsuSFpZGGlLOvzfAwmxo6jqnBHjvJwMk5gmoyMg0v6EIXmGjP@eCXJHkXPgJ03Tl9C1BfRVh7hvoxO52GvSAzOQ26jrnoX1xXMi9iPHMoSrFGcjSUJ@U04h2wIj3y56wXCJmbjDsjZ8F1Fz7FOpzboj2PsJPvxBa/GKgoCUDHAcz4Zoh614tEWE7MUGkMjIJqsOU/Qeh0g1PCb3wVjMGKnxbdH@8VvaOfP/WOH7ifel8//e4xJlokm1k2rxb1YbaRWHqs0MxY9DOvxiotNq4GP/WyGT71lNxhsUhAiBTdo5@Lx1@LhNCnRc97UPy0KATJdBkwKc6vrwjwxSk0F7NYFBedBe@BZzrf/bHsKZpb@Rd9KB88@SUszKKSt@lpnTPsECi@p/vbhVw5iYtPV0uPVsuPaCV0Gl7nh@EF5tt8fHESXpMqEWM5S1PPp98z3JAhxLfrOFinj9fUTglrIndPYn1JSYtQPcy5HidhKypTEJ6g/ERldpeKKy5ekifA4SMW/L4iljN52ReUmA5a3Odi/oz756gniCHXJm@HCEfCykBsRHgLNQ/IJvjKTRzqmeGyzPecCmoLvlsZCHVvcdGaLXr9Xl4ra15heR1KNG7NdJ@WnpYmx@jUEM2M0CWtTC3fU@WNH5/82//c@21xtLixWvwwpN/R4m@La08X5ZEe6O2hebtc3Fh8jmxr3xbHRVoD0@OTf/vfVH7jLwQHKePn9GfjsYG1Nl7cyFe5yNfFjTV6KK@uUr3/51//ldqwJCs2xGJdavqKEVs3FNkKesy7lK4aaKUsS5dTscIXswBDLAxpbU4vMIy6Xn1a4m26RW1VcRlqz1fGHkVP8WyYNWJTIdnJMPYUpBlJgSoqyAtIY0LRUZbthjHbAPOmaKpf7hfWYloB/KLNOZIqE9ON@zFMhpZkWUQd6EqNtJ6Xh43Sj7nEvKOSMzYl60aFxNJOy9qnD9eJHd72w1HUylpJmOF63gquwpMC@LAQti9oTdWLu/1fh8VLYsnz8urTYgeb@0W24y4OGFJ@MC78ToqgDgZEC0M2OvXVkHqgfw4XXj5HCyKFfic5kzLxJEnLHoQt2cPKxiSmLHLHz5fjYTSnkKrSLv8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qceldzbr6jcSpJR8vGa1wM2b9k4VrvAyIs17IBlU8HhNmB30LSnUBue8iUkLgWv65KlELTbzUCnuc5CzoRK852Fs7A7qOY64t4dvlNxYqLpL2rmjVDyEXYQ8nkWdIB1Ho4CWqJXc/wF6/G0BrhJ0Wetiau4lKwdnVev6ttVjroyp@orqfqKehRaQlpPwjOWNzZlZxPZUsVW5TBs4khtZsVUW2yCNg8L/AMMYumWRgfXEnRz@AYkUS1tjrYqs7vN57Uw8chVKHf2ZGtRIlc7i@nlR9/kkBvU0J1Qb0EqIwEBL7gVWCjT@4HcgKiaMKNRzxF/fhPJxr@HBsNt2IMrUdttnTgflWmpd4nYN9GI71IqIoH2K2vbYDsyeySgExdbSQjaHDZech5YqlPhxRZnNN1R4TDQxiVULif7VEctlYSX7ejotRIogj7kSuXVh48erz15@gxRzhZ0a2eDQaECVgGDs4BgsEbt0iIb36vV3HJOPiEE9XSVgD4LLA7gYNZ15XnG7fOVd69aLmlgpRzDuuIwGlJcb1cyyBTiMCxgRqA1ijvMue6PlSM07PhT2/tK/4i/jX9AZjjjjjYQ0lv98Db1TOWci8OBKgtmdorjPoQHFU@n2HnDfmcf3iZC2LoK21NFr@EBYnQ27F@cntncUdCurQ5pwBDB2S81VlAvw1HqYMzCCrqo3nBoWLcvqgbe0XQLYJSLKQE6nwCnYab9Vgba0hSjY5kmIXjWxI1VHCFapqM2OzN39vqqvrs9idiiHYaO4RZsy1ZS7tiTGRzIIFav1dxDoq72dsFXSbVM8jNelVnAlZCvzNfhA9yVbiEQtUUVI6tZbxi588hSZl5MXZumRakfgdcMmOXS7aQ091pNK0AQIwj1blIixPzkPMcmWYqT3ckYp@DlXMWyEX0TxTE7mNOV5TxtUcqZOKrAgnMDQOzblHLSkFIFPcqPdQ68LL2NYI5yKxpbA9oMOVmphjNzcpgJtrqNxQE2oo4bWqD9jd0tX23X6c/Oh20fivJm7Se0OwnxfDO@ZY1vuaIaO6YLbG@xbHMLm6nfcEWJmKWkHcamCEL4diQqYph6Dag3djTtZVAfZcb2ccoVYNdAK@Fmd1QPEjh64T2QBb14T1xx8HUd/laRzatpSZO4VNHDQra45g9siyYLaa0JJCHlHUCsToJIHLWk3L6QMrxYoLPmHei1i2Hsxs5sns6wrCyoSG3fKRLZszx7I2XmscWqZovVCvpxHl8w387ljZOw09d30RLmuIU37v0x3sjfnTny/18wR/2fwx0PNXc8rED2CHckbsP5RieHYe/P4JiTMc/BzXZ0GmF/qGO9ohEl3wLAAg8Y4g4pJZZLaNsN4kS5sxNWJucjGAmtPsbFgD/U@Ee68Y8qkLn8uB3@v9r4/D@48Y914x9XMNfM6Hmt2lnu1v8xLU5VQjf7YWb3Qt2VbN4fbemabulaBbPpjG7@T29p/j@opU90S59U4DFBDhzEff18bhZNpHaw1Wik5hYFRzvtchHHfjZXelh7tas5Wjx0uhfxWRXauvrD@D/V@D@FNOInhKHDWURiG5qs5WV5KpflRbPkXQ6FS1bSEmmv8YxutVdPWOl6RE9QIqR5Y2uoFyqkkPuSmJ42FVL9MZW@yeRzV5xFtutgmTg4txbQsiIse@kQF81XB8lcXUvmlW32gay2Dvdfr/wXIcN58FnfQiPk0bVXYbdrZhJ7CXaYeJ3SjbGaA9gHes2RYRVNTkZ2pG97J@yycLNUY8cWE/Pi7EWCHLXh/I/WUufQN6yo3NgyItoUdHmzqoJprlleyBdqu2Sa3WTd4j/Epc80lz6rqH29MLiJVIHe8NO8mK7TVh8/njcHSKkCfjAASz7lnzOq/i8)

This answer also adds [FungeJ](https://github.com/TieSoul/Funge) (422).

RubyFunge prints a warning to stdout when it encounters `D` instruction, so now all the Be/Trefunges go down on `v` on the first line instead of reflecting on `D`.
Befunge-98 takes path of Befunge-97, then Befunge-97 is separated with `2222y$-`. `2y` [pushes current coordinates](https://github.com/TryItOnline/befunge-97-mtfi/blob/master/idefs.c#L2362..L2365) in Befunge-97,
so `2222y$-` will result in nonzero value on top of the stack in Befunge-97. Fourth `2` is for Hali, in which `2y` is noop.

After that Be/Trefunge-98 is sent up in the same place as before, `|` on line 1 is no longer needed.
`^` or `|` cannot be used on line 4 because of MiLambda, so I use `[`.

[Perfect hash](https://tio.run/##nVbbctpIEH2WvqJDigSMWOvGzYAf7MRV69qHVPKIqZSQRmIMjChd1sEpf7u35yKCiLTgUCVGPXSfOaenZxq/G/n@6@t7yvx1HhCYpFlA47@W1/qvqQ3ZxMmOz@nvAxJSRoCtPRalYLs6ZRlki/VMzsxngzlM4aeuXV6C/Fg79WLLF9Pq2vw3cwXvlL3iL86nb190zbLAkGGuHGGoRlON1pFdjLjg3c3N37pmD1Wo1ZNj1yqPUDcixJfdXc4iwlF6ZZRaIvbvKH5YgIzkZB@OKNSBHKghCsSxFYg7@FMmXcscIVDfPSHJrAFGoNtbnlun3z@CcGtCK7h89S9Vcp2@kmJCGaY2Pwd5uf@2RxmWUWqjK1Bu13GaJTSg@YYjqRQ71onMVCAJNp0OogzMN5bMAUpS7PbAqqbStc44AIhBOYZ95i5VYKQZZatlnDCO45zA@R8u/@B9kHsRubq62VfywK3e9nPS/O4ApncmrQqYzc6PhbSikPtvp7IIQ46gatiCt7P4nMaIMByeWS8V6X0uklFcMSdzWnGo74uTNLKPQN5QdM80ElxGQw7kVAOdI4nRzQHQqJzdk5f4AdDXfFFc46597lGoO9n3@sv4V@ML6L/Qkr2u47Z13V96yQVEJOOXCYtavB0yVnTDto6dMM28jPrAPUF6zTjKBTjQAUu0S0wXLqJho01J1pJOBnyEjwak9JnEoZprQxesNnrqWhgnIFZ7RABzjMNEdWV873TauoZLa2JRlm9m7hyjtJRtESYLWzhl8Ew0ml0naBiigz/OZ@a8PebC5fQVJDRaZt2tFwD25SeaLcGDdOv5mFhO1t/uWh@UJAcFofDH@dwAge5wni@6riUkyxOmpI91nOK0Nx5lLZEfoSRnKY0YCWAds0h@USmMorCWla/XMJlgH72APnKke4XI9olwmikaexS@gofxLQrX1yLKbMMHMH84d@Njv0XJz6r180t@dq1fUPJzav1Iyc@t9QtLfr1DPxpCy8PJBT4@PgE@BB8MmXLFeNXhbZ4TLGB0LpUmDz9dQyLFPPICkvgJvWSh8GBN7DZOcQL44wxLuSOYcMPmhq8MhxuBMlxuEGX0uBEqoy9xxYooTOJPuI4ozmL4XlKjlm9O@ZHcx@0VraSiFcY/4iDFSDUF@GrOsyRgfltB/HWK12uaUt4tNCxkTRQzr7cwzlkAW5KExM9g6aVLnFcHq6GKcTpr2gFUPEi52QyATfHrodFMHxoPDA@gZ8DCAN@AwABiQGhwWYbaDePggmGs3eYJ2HO9Esfs5fX1Pw),
solution:

```
weights=[47 23 50 38  2  1] %28 n=24 "329284   38839237137637028538937437711 372399422367368366369   289364373   375393   "
```

Second `11` is for Affine Mess.

Answer (score 2):

## 401. [Plumber](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber), 16918 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._'4o'6o@<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';       # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]























































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata_;re7^0::Prullasge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!48 ?\在ｕg=2\0C05+---<?ML42yalet d=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4oequ@  5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({bfacabf0-7afd-4359-a8e4-9a7a7f1d9258}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0kiwRAAHyzyOrq6urbfdUvdVffey2SzQZJkEQXCLABsors6uqQNLtay/bMejSyQ5Y9vrJmPCuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzkJgGAVWdVXtje8iyoC@Tx58mTmyXMyEwddwx/99KcJvNgT114MbXfKpqY/ZX3POjE9md1esFuG5Rc0XRAw1b43nI1NZ@pXhQRTGbMNZzgzhiYbWPbU9LLMN03WNW33FOI1xnZnzsw3@w3w6Yw55im77/SsPkBgU/fYdKw3pgdxecbumPbb8dsp67njseH0fTbxLGdKsQXGnhjgGcx6x8zo@lPP6E0t14GoImPPHdsYd/sGo@QTz@SZSgxA9Y4pz2pMmbGHruebUILbM33fxcAKBBqe5T7Yf/TRhfRqjn1kAFIT25xfKF5V2aeW6fUv5tDYJ0d3714M1dlXJNdhdy@jpObZ/mzq3p9ehF9g@0PTMZgmV2TtYmQRiDk17XKunLsYVYL2NKdWb6UciLhredC6RtCKrGc40FrYljvMHE@mCybx9jdsO2pbnxk@m/kzw6Z0zmzcNb0woT81vKnlDNmpNR2x6cjyo3yU2p8YPVPqm7Y1tqZmn9kWZHIHARQA7fTZsbk4dT1o8gCm69gLyGj2rIGFWUI8ACBeqenI5HDGxgIa2ZlC52AG8wEN2wyhpYUEpL9jdmdD5s6mk9mUAW59yze6NgDtLljfHBgze5plXYgDIlP46ch0gs4M4GQAceRyrF7NCDVz2eeNfp/loB8DHscms4BqhFaV6TqEM9cDqkGqEKMAGPVrXkdzDm0GTTRwq6yQy0H8YRSC2Bq27wbIrKKGkQ6MVWozhPvEc4eeMQZq9E2i6Sf3nzC/53rggx@m5ePpKjA9Y8p2d1ny8NGdJGtEzSJ7XSFqojo7gyZIhJHsxLBn0EPiLeFC@3hRbgGbLLmVrLIkkEXLsXye5WHYlplWACKpuQo4YPxrugq/ItPKLK/CCCowXSsls1jWwDOGlm1ySEOEVMLOD0k0uOfyTFfLPOXQtQc8WY8KLDG9zIolViqwEtwrrKJBiQg@z9RKAX5F@AG0CqCjwk/Pc0DLvg99FfvbARsYY8teBNAJfI8VVFYCiICzCpC1MkCAp67jT4cfobV6xWFPR0DxkXEC4CXbOkaOZEZMCZtRgYeys6MQV0S2y4v3R1g8kA8IVyizEhRfBErkAQWgrlaG4gs5XhF/ZNp2kG3kYzbCtpSDH2BeAjqUoQVyQMscErMEP/ADz9OAuWnAyTRgThowFE0Dt45FQLoixBWhOYsBvUaGfwwF8XK0PhEfuDqAUZHayMhUJBJAgNZiOrRZkeWhM@jYGQo6A/wBl1KRAS8rq6ycZ@USA3pWcgzaRgW8sKeowENVwEdFYND@KnQAFXBSgdoqAFX1AhNixFZ1jIe8OuQF0qh5yJMHNzScWsQf5IOeoUKRKpSpaZVlRwTctALUt6BTD9WK0LoliAO6aYCrBt1JA2y1MsRj3jLQsIwdGLotJ4SBdIBWwS4P/RCIUQB8CC6kBbdW0jn9DHsyMrrIsXnO7gCzFnEoFJGMkDWH1YNnHqkJqOQADI4CQF@DHqDTiIFnPireVgFIE8GbfYuYtG0B/1IjCpWy1CFfGZPpkmxqkTCaLKajKEzjYS4wTwsYoDk0eosoEkZfNopchhZ1DNWI3y4B5fIY6gN3dWe@vQQSOfIaFWWeWPYyrExhfdPoDyx/9G6Ja54K6ZrG1LGOl6UUCtkYUY1YRBEjVoJKejzt1JJgyhqO0LWsi1bCNBM3aqAVlFWV0Ouag5kzNKVKOYYfxUxn3hQml2WZFR7sWcMhzMtLOGqWqkmT5TK4QBjauj4VokCkLpbpWTCF32S9EQgVUWSFw69UljB0DWEsjC7O7BJIYjATVHDuGlhz1r3Zo5ljiaBOdOqNrEmYuLoxcaxxqZB5uRjrG0S5N@VcxJrxasuvXMtJJVkyLZwLMN9w6TI@W8Ok9inOVDj3YteFudUlyWHJPlNOODumgWirEz3MvDawUWiUnoGzMM5JJs2pIRxrKjMoBERB0z1B0ZUmxpVifJo8ux5KqiDp9E3PY5gWxFs/S9OsP@v65usZylJLvAYwb5swvQ8My44QoHnEmJIQAM@kD@UtVtEeeO6YJpsxTqO26042iCwwaZ8ioHvuqblEfTmnG5OJDZIThJtccANkTg2SuUlAj5fKEYJMmA8aHABSUSBxWJ7ZI9oHVYfcOsgmqyhWmda4qSOU2zGRSofBAuKGj3mcmW1XQdYxe0xvKH3zRMEQLnatiluIQyiIgTgVgOgaIC8j5oRFBOmmJpOIdxS2rO@OV6vG59f7UdVHFgpH9qmxgNYbwNRqzo0xSPUMRWcYuWwMPYa3ILYE6C1Yrfus7zrJaQTl1ANBFiod1YSEZaTJ1BqboAG5kAVbPE9I4@xOmHUX0JWJWnmZVB6OyQVCycJFQvGAfCyADxYQ@fqzHlINy7Yc6kEgJvko53vAKnmYMPVYq2XAzwOZbhJoeTI6MOEzRC2mJPh8tAfSd48gopxqOj6oFr7MLNTBoOcP3QF0tlML6g4MC7IuYfeICEiCKGgu92SBSI4daHxsM4v1JhMG4TApQfe8myuDGOq@stgbiLRHoEb0Zp63YPMJtIQ1hlTTnjsYQO99Y05GAIKN@6y36MHwhEbG3iP0XWIwvclqNZe@bRPSOKiYHDz5eTY0gewgtA5QQ8Uuv6zAZEJVIFIYDhdoHQMohVXoTRZEFiGxzDFwXRnD@67pU2dxveNo6GNhvjmkoQHjbLBkRmMU0KGXOqRY9IHzBMML4WOBwtrKYFFBL/jIdGDo9KBXwqCH5sM23WcDULRjIizqGkavZ06mQT9xiZ1ZTkzmf3wXZX4KlQJgsj8Stm@x3Qu9BpJGPScmy6IOhKhPAlXEQF4baPMSCR6R2sk5i724VDykOLlQuvgS06xg8FLcgMOEhgQqQMQkZlNkJcgdrd4IeeEUuQ3J2zDavNnl6kNYvHhvzKRBVDZiowLbEWQlCkI8NsOQ4GdfBiRPbITVWAnApCsB14A2/PEayG6EpN2Ph8qKIQNTvA7o2HXcNVCBmBFcTLIaQ21BnfEZcg3DjjojDRd/pY2QYS8XmHAigzl0MnE9GBmc6SxoNYGaLNa7AiU8Fc0VaZndXp1aYcpI4oQ/xVkQMkxsA/oCDjEcqaBZGcApgIlxJRl4nstLjCFMo55gBfidEuvnnQnmUscxUTkzvAUHAtWD6RkKWjDL84ANnuAkweegcDKRqZ/CnGD0@8hZkRw07i8WLmOPPph1rflFTbyHgfIrXzgxPDZAJdwDoQMGUSo58JPpGoVTzliUqLiTqUJZ@V2EhJRIhiZPDUCvh0niLjCaZwunlxJXhpiYZeJsOiiLaXBgRi6jsY9BVbiIHaoP2GnGxzCuyVdjQ5i@JQnuEoYRJhihyBhheCBnwCAELbNS6XcN9ha4h8ek@QFXRUKVRJXzUVmm04/KCgiBuMTrK/MifK9HDik2q2ENMDnVnCaJFQJ@ICUoowgBihLMrRhA0h6PI7mGB84cWotjKS6KpNlZJPzCBJAiZCwQPqyeNe0E4srNm6HgslWvQ2cDaQrYZj8d12jDRUsZODUklkkaCQqRp@6zKY6NVBrqi4nPOTYgNkFPrTfY2XTkwYgj/7kAiYCsgoM9OSRs0M6PrONZ/2JDOxiIiUQcdSA0Wb2pWBNg8uejoX4VVZMrVAWtN4lUxc6L@Qn0pc5LodigYpDMM30Uf@sBKrEWTiEGQV9dSyKeNQhbduiDRc8ORALugsHOuVEX0D8OFrMiRpQNZIJw0F4aqRwIDgcOhz3ZP7pXD8Yij1S6llNdCbDdnmFT8DYmF8O8D@7ffrr/9Oc7a2DYVrd6MUCx8uUiTrWzuTR0Zkpe1qrbcRhLwHc6V8PGjKtpRCGIZpI7j4lKix5MLvOQnI@ffuUiSUASQnJQCeDG3wWRhqcBoUvoGv7owiTMhpkMFBllCdMy6T4LYUYORB3jjRCfJ7M3b7DxLiI1CcIRM3tmcABhoHLfCfPJGHlBAAujugM@I1JekEItBzcblq54yhCfj1BqvogMidKxLvPR47uHT@sENlhXkyiJ4k9BljK8vgx93p6BCr4uDbA/cPVYRl4ijvI04bqWwL3eCoGXbcs2wAcAqOvILpPscVg1fwS4H1ysG4VKvagHkJ8gXJQr4/JQ74siGsMDp7geqrzrZlGKWE5WUdDaGSuKXZ22eoWCWcpX4tNWb1lmPw6UNgZgHgjlRg@ijn0JQ@SlFBmI1QH6zx5cQtwnIRJUASnEzLeZTGX5toDai2SxpK8cgIbm2qb8KXE8kYlpRUmGewNyzyflM5b@cG5NU7k0f6ppSAul7@/f1@6EiYMla1rJIKUBdXGcmbwB7vH1fOgjjmu7Q5ftQB4uHYYFgti0sZr7Q9e51EIGBmJVE7hNCPwXF26MCcw11htSHClXXF3lG46G458Cl1aLOhKJKESgFEovvzJODCDXst7P7n/tECYRtZDLRe4cXUCCWB4iF7p6sVAKYBIUJAf4rK1gtGV4abSHEVJszw4rHTC6KOP@MnptIHFMWVmbfi1KH7uXKP7KXVzoWhDCuxY4YiS7/@jJg/uPDh/uf9aaaoXCij@fqxSBcFBeF2QhecTphqN1hw9NrBaCS8DY8HB4AReYgYIS7hjNfA8Yt4xJZI7Ahl7DN1tTH7sjJ@mnL1bmFGOlV06Pd6GHOPh40iAjKNp9G5URj@9Y43yO/Wc0nU78qqLAKB/NujIorcqrnmsbQ4XywcRg24qKqsv9x7iu4a/LAcj4C5Pn4ItbIDosaAXRsMcuKC@0742sgaU4eFq1sq3hCHRh3Bw3vbQc9WCqjdIHDQF0ZSWqGzFg8gFtg2fYTiLv2l9WtTLv12pOyytimGxl@EParYEJqlMKZisgRfqCl7Vutm6yBXBphHQRSILJO7TI4TOcC2wGgiStmqKeHxKHuAWulyKvIBq9nuFqLnAppZDLl9RiQQG1DNQ0kFklXHOTxsa0N5KmrgTwJHdA6waxXjjwe4YzkHcCR4gsyH03oKp680Wr5bRBQG/dJNxw77m5aDfVdrrGLmfZCdKna9B7V6qHfTcMgL5LTuia9GQb@FnfuMzO@gaNrj5TpuNJMOdIE/ZwHwSpNy7w674ZH3uYQYlHKjsraRVM/E5ZsyBkY1YBb0gpBQYUzLTQ9RTESwKhF8VD6DnAt2IZ2HI1IxKYFtMR8A@dpQ7Ilb4s4WKwHnCNVVRwUVieLIDlUSJk2pKOCIURVOCEQ0BUkqACocSD8UmOAj9mEmNlqPfj0LPcpE/bNCha4YKtP4F2pPXuHk4UPi5RTmGCjgYfThTQv3CeYKdmEpfyDZ8vmEKm4KhBmB/UxQgCbQxEi@JOdLgC@iHlohUCYF7QtXHldrRc6MR1B@jsUCDhhOsfIMQ4tIExhEpCZl6RfV4RXhKFrFbp2HFPHYTWNVlZ6lpTvt/gzjzccrf68bpBcl3jaQAaVS42tdDefNfs8YVenplqAXqowcbm2MXVDBDwiBuZVAWD7@ujOurjojmM7JyEm5YAX2K3DoCR9ky@ZCWNUY@DXn3IklNP2Ze@phjSGxhQV4h3WPlYEweNfhQSYPWUBS3UBIuwJCC5Y0r0KS35YOTtUOIOuhb2LNGouxPTuah2cqU0la7RaYhkku9DnSW3traS1WQjmQXXHrh20bWHrgy49sglkQvTyeiiHFlyYWyTcmBYO3neDCHP023sA3MUXt5Yk5TRrFb1dtZoqsFTw2camgIoD6klfACcZLpeR2c6LTZOcdsIVIhY3Q@w7zzredYkIMHHIJNwf3x4icHw8swaqsdXU2Rc90BvNVHKTXnJVjPXarfOWv1M6zyZxdzpmlEHFRX45zQ1loeeO5uA7NjMVyVgr@mmXm3XuvVkLrmTSpUlGwoy0ukb5XTG4LROJU3oU6lWKwkkDajT7I08gjfPaul0RCjAY2CBomPbqaR8Vobyu@l2OpOEvOlkFmaGejIJdKE9T58qjYsSvBPdteZAShiYMMvGtzWIR9P@GA7Xr5mT0cKLJ4gW/kDQx0X85ZEZPFmEE0mcUb/h@eMy5cpiQyh683QgX@P6IYpskwWfYASOaUtZOaAVTv0n0mDsTg3lExn0Njk2Yye3kookwWRMMRwSVfuh5eMQNhzTnfnxxc61a7BYOoQejWbALMNTclnoVdZEMHsjlyW3bwF0Fm05IePH3TOJ78GFAPo9GX7IRFEwwv0aEHDoXJMFfJFOhNHCkEpIcNYTbg8UipPXclRajfKwHBZkDR3XMyUgCeQQ6BAXHQ0UGuHW@H1afLs0/QSxNKviVGaZwBHv2q5BtOXsOrYlNRnH8jtDzPLU7As28I8BsEeZt4Vn9pUdgTaKXW8EMwTUBjmxFrXWOIhQXH/Sl6dzyCqkcM6PR3IFE@TeU9bXNK3YKwyqYRz2CiD2CBoJFWMHtOwwSlIhMh008iFfmQqXCR49vnPIl29ovscZHpfyOmO3PwPRNlDdnprOMMsOoT9Zjju2gAxh/jfH9lPXnfKFBvBsWhziers1ntkGLTtdXBm6Ml/P7bo2rUZdlXWZfub5hm3wdbAwdv@Th6BuPD96VpersUSKcTK@smxcCl1fLKfn/fi2J235hjtUPu@Y4nZBxHkrPHyKbCaIKGLELDh6Cm0UhpcwPBxSuI0ThJcxfIzHTkFcDxYyyBsFBgkrlBCPouK5uyDwTM2dY/hGNTBKp1I6LrsusT1TNQo/mQ4GK8E6BR9LyJrsZXCegvmR1BU1NY5SgSfC86kraeKAipQmOqa6MV2J0vEDNnK0ufkwOgcxMu1wd/MpSCy4gweTvo1yFehNqCXwo6QmCPkT3Kgh1o3bf6wHcrB/SYqFwTaReGohsUUDCCY3BUUaYVthwfJ7jYaQ4wbbpj5nq66X5Ss7uw2@0Y5qncc1SoVvDGx3AMRuoxae@duUDEtKJqNkBJVwgxxUTTpbcKmq0UkRn9b7BcpSE3wFNJq5lpNa89Jh@21S8YkMAya2WvMbOe0zUI3w0Ob2TWVo1uiY1QZ61cKYZCDDdhdMAokPU/G1894I@AzLzFdJCe0zcwau3Zf4Rh10GMZVPGyg4JxEdJg0ODNsWl54jpQO8vKsyF9jR1Avwb3QpI3LCWKHViNAMHzO2Nvj7Mlb1oQp70T2J7Y1bbNzeep2RsFhLefi8VYug3qesfCF4JhNne0//eiTZq7NIQhjAzffyrwV5@EpaRCcQVDC4@zgwsNCU2tKkgAdhrCwvqoMSM1pnwbQBxi8gBqLCgpqhKi/Nd8u6zIwQVlOmYi5vxhnmZk@lwe2MZ2aDu9zfAd0M7n5VlVQTJ2K3wv2PaosR5tDIJlaGAco1tizozuHT5/K0HP9VPIQN5GqMByN3ggElE2VDikZr3yV3egn2Q3Mk8aVAwGGGmgfnSA/dOoadHrQP6B05B1D00tBYBr3f3oQTFtulJFLaAGB8MhXb0o0ioClzDTUiYBV1@L/3OGqVoBnFXp8higJ5E7drAJtrbQ8c6zXsg8TDcmtkCRQVmG@qG@niIttq@ngTN8Yd69BwyKhEWrQbDLpDXA5SCyydrvGjyFAWlTAvCFSVxSpKegwfV0Nm74OwSDSEIQge/0de9HMSZV2ZnsdKDrfFpyD5/WPwUUIq6B9c22x2yka75cGMseBb0dyzv2c1OkLL4FU2TZ3iHzZm5KHZ7aI6dARr9WjWqsHwWCQISuh1SCsSMgSEsFbCkGfpXji/KDzYDYKSKXZWUR0DUnO3r4lGrJtjRENwaUy3hjnofYJjOmBC7V5ELyhEJcOaLQGZ1lwzLYEMVSzVjeLMYaL8MrJBelUOhHj@bh0aDnHLm05Ra5OTlYLKBFGucfH9uWceA6WbitJIxx4Wm0Tdv64O6DbmgS08xLs6VMArekHsjAIkYbylB60vL@m5NVzLCvFBidkaaYFN5NeX5NSqpQp8aDbtTYlBSLg0bTwuSYZMCnsz5qcl9XwlQdcioH5CBgX116WVb94BIqt0D04yhs8/@vX@0D/y60zgokCFz8jRwembmwpabCxsYKs6KHb@obla/Qz2zKIMOS6DmTP8KBKhh051oOmcwCSBNP/GHc1ghaHvok3kBqv6GYcc74pGT7XF7JuX88BltnblPbCkTBeFO1AgWLXJyJwIcgyKROxLt4I5pzvAsVUbGRj1yMVntti1Jl5u49m0xm/g@B6bSNaE/xdNTaDlLmC0VVNhR@ev6LJPeN41nelyfEwklOLa9Iua0/b0BKIA8GOdAed66vPK8gPo4fPTcmWU5tySo/reoXvzPyJ1CUtvM99NBDGV5Tg2fy@KYkVvEMYOTZTzbLp9oE9MYAOHSU4kKHgcVcpRjTrAplto7tAGWT0xXtZdLgBOE69l8nk9A2725PJ5vyoSVL@SmV97rnc4/RYt0ag8CO1El9FowoHh2yvaVWYrqyxYUtaP@bcyMzXnY24lDTaVqU8@P4HvQRyZSfHCak3sw1v6bqiiy/xCLcRNq1IB9PGE6vngjgwYWpJVrVw6ohNGMQyw9N5y4LwRDPdYicwrHVkDN9okSLXehbg9qZ4anVDn/oAhsZPi@KZ3Fgnkd1NlOq5p/jbKD6MQDXl9/Uz2pu1WH0Ac5Lsnm3APL5xOlhZHMTFx2s66qnlm3RbT9jjtYhOe/ba8NUhEC77xZfxruvWvmW7PntG96sINPSACvy@vkPHaWkZjkSL4XH3FTwoPGaxbFDDHrp2sTxUDLhtbPWZN0C@Hzw/lMNFHEpVr@FQofjjOmrw3MjXjxXv@LoGoncmPTxiG3NeMcWuY1PB3svm2oFigBt362t2N1emnLLCl/o2FIxbLqfGInz@DFPHJtKGU8dkQeI0SHeYoVIGx9TjIvbPUlr@6tL6H8aULoEtXVeJWOMe2yZMVnS/1KRMy6lfMIeay304ixrYM3NmrlU0Hndfmfh2/xVKxocjlQuqsR2s1OPmAL4dE6V6E2iGH4Q1ztPou5KZGLbVM68XZVaZ2gSk7wmqzk/A8QQdl3MMndlkpVVXtDPn6dUkG03CIe32V7DDmC/Kh8rXSEor8rlv0u9KjYlreHhGrV7I5XKBABPbcVnxXKVJ6VHeVxa/rxRMIcuSl2lxl82LOdeXQWSJn4LcyIK0TYo9Ja5UFMdyzOkC7x/ITbuua3@RlgKmiu8su6CtSnTa96oWuyTuBO@xsOXShY8LHt3BpkULPtsEuiXQB5Xmqxo9viX0Qa0p4abnGDekVr1XL9/ENpiuKwXfr8U1IX7@194sSwarIapclktXjjouobpd0zb4Y17MXwWvIutXwltlGsFmLW7u8i3d5VZ84gJTmiyAWFYftJSROTbJe4WUb/TRUkfw2Jho7uJvU/TcNHvK/NDsbUowsYAvOHhf2UOOCUtT1wH9aopHDVFPsfEwaxC6iQOHu35riXx/bAxNbjrmKk65XLDA0zRcrVs61y9dVPkJmh5kW9oE2dwlYFAdmws/fK4F@HDRg3adja9fbrsw@Hu4BvoBo33TKdrLU6wzckfOyBzxo@uRb9PggP445aZ@rkIdsB6O8DTdZLJyyj5OT9u17Q@hJ7JGzihdd7AWp0N8/xZfHvtCcPnL/sHj2sU7Y8p5Bzo2jpqROYN5yXen7sSUyLcpqY0LPfy@iYeGm9Q/6wrSlXo@UCR8/qzwr9Uth4Y7nUzo0ZnYM59ulFWi16avk5sG/GgKnct0vaH8xh135SBQDs6t0Bb4ehbTtaa9Eb63znu2OXS7vZF1HdKBrQwlXPLh3g/SXZEyFpPuYLBsW0BebyFjf6nH45/h4/6mRg9Wj/i0FjmukFfWrdDRm@HSxDju@Xw1FF2sigvCsdHI3x@v0hv41dcza7oEGjvLFC3v8m0JdGzCPTg9sVGyotc0lmw4OFWxsZeSkI4CuWTmQOBRNxW7es4tNsR0nd82IRSvJWEUO5fyRcgdnP2h1UErtm4L4Sv9a@XQ0tpJzhnNhv5lhsmX6/sgouFt87IFHaeOLVnDnGU4wWMTmTVbwfcs4dkBmWtmXrmnUrhyU4XSqbZkuBY8OvCAppttXEOzrYnP70wabNyKC84ygS5@cb@Q02axXpkOGqZvDvgWCLquExHHrocnkUEGkXq4k44r6MjMueDFGZfjDoGpSzZbJg7TbhJb1h4TWt/80ZwpffbIHBp41vqBNcXDmmt6BXXZdceLroX91ZnhW1@dQc02dTY0GsG3Ib24dQH0rYH30BhavXsrDREhGRA4OOnJHyvdH4Mut8XpyPLxRFPkuGJhCrsc78TY6zqgN6xJeXHdPrKXsRxA/E3MtanXra27kwW@sLYg11XL6taUVlmD5ybVcdMhsCuROJ2NJzM/eKzHgc5MxVehx8cU7p9aAFx6DayVjQx7un6lOrbkClJYMCkunZuk8a9ZtjtkXyvnGAhtIIShcL6m49yG6fkJHsjxnDU9kcr@wG1PXOiQPF6x19C2Jr5X4VjTq1dzplM8nBM@sTJ85sA3FJQHeJdvfVEI0tF6ijy4XtZfvh19zfwOPe@ZO/N6JjojkydxtSAo1TwITx/jGx0ummw5jWtpPdeG4QUOe@2Q6bnObCp5M@fKWaF45axQRYNXsW7AUl89fPg8He8NdFr7Oik0NIm2dG08MHChk1kOCGKb@ehq6lCXuMNNNT2lo8LX5NlHe1I9Ytd33HX6zpMFTCAfrDAB85@N75g93Da8tuxH7kPXcWE2mgCjHD81udmBlYMe6zNitgf4Yj3Qp39tMc8I7IZJiEsbxsTsQvvaS9eHzEUc8B1jamyYimhtkPS/yHVtX7Hsrum9okW/mHuTSruK0D1zTrrF5g7Dx6A07fW4SIzrcStjZGXHxp@4rsPvxG1z8FAfXs1VYCqg24dvlMt4EH9lXWCtfrZa1ccn/JSI2ed2MTbV1TO7rs3vV5xJcix@JsDwLNNXHqCZBQor5pkE0pd/JQ8pXclDlqoRSLInhk@b9OtVjSVIdf4FjgCNDK/n4k5Y4LjidE7MNsI1bDo6288PDnSB8HPgWEZvFtgrvQ4te9wd022jwhBrzadmF98K6pJBkakxv9yYfGUosKYQO9EV2SAI2RUO6iJLPQFtJH39tLWiR61S1ZrQjTj1xu1yOqwjOZbZe2PgqplL9FquTa/EQ52VR@TcsFYdG0a0iqwY9LL92pG0enQNBBrblKYjD3R@ZXrV8nZo6WXNfshsbOIm8@ouzEbR1fVHVFl3/X56xFw9UwrMDQIviUwPcvlQ2t8oeSJ4@H98@2MFJuFOMR9aPwHWdf0OPiA/85zg8SE98InrTwfW/DHgjW8BbGInWK0CZIEHHxno2tlUCWg9Z2bz1Ydh7NzVuE/qmETGoCXJJnY9NSXTOZHIFt38co1c/tKXso8GhKdmXwpMMeBOg/QgfP8rShY812ygxnkjHvZUFU7YeTEfHP9cR9zTkDOAvOVOpYlPT2XiP7n/4PGRPPHVtfPT/gjfjrgkx63YdtDKudiS1CvDi@138uNofcufKrefqdLBg/syJthAb76jIcEDd@ZWHhvXPUNDsoqxUQvCWHO6XkC8d/TwQWb5iiZLHYw8d2ym49EHz55l8U2Tj5@tjY7nvgujY@DON2a/f6iq6TXd97lDu4ObuOeakjZBOjJBG4XOeI@bhrlWuOq5E7N/tJiYn8DkiRzc/8Diixsr@cg4sYY4ClllI6FooLKKXMynYyezQdk2vei5qT2PrQlyyx49FP7YeBwFJQdd8fT10sNVO/4XpRiWC04ifLFMau5yb42bMlYM/@@KmKqqm@j8zBhAu7LCxsZaTbBuf9h2Tz5gK9kMlBcpCpKm0Ksk69pz5CVpDKxbwRsuzweB4OxuPAZzFYAouLh2wJ@azsJwJNrLukq8qEJuPNR2ZZKvmR@wIRWd8DlBe@lr9/iiI/Us1SNn@pqCj7xYloOD2/evy/A0oOXVqT569Jw9MXy0g3J1wjjG5gdgvJSMXkm4boVG@DZup/Y9AKVdCW84WT@eq@yZ4fVdZzG/fhOO3kHFqZ3sG0ew0EeJTNuaW@vmqh5f13qy/pjRdWXzlzjcxYocHLePEwB6/61/oaq5HFk/wqea495rWiYc4CyFLmOBJvXiUUf3I9bQQ7lFhoD0Wm30gTnH4yh8NXidUr92fiteMfeV0punk6viylfE5a8o71IcBjJdzqlXACxcEccKchT9wLVPR658YHimv@b88VqErqpI5YqKVGLcOTDYThuLgXuziI@vLgSPtb31yJx6@cnI7Vr5tXXYH6CdS/YQ7bVfjg@OUxgeHW8ZusErH9y/vrzTmbm2oIfGm/URxGmO10YBEzRHM3ol4nL06gZpF2Re0xla3MQju@1OD8l3hWIWvfG8/iyCNbkzm2zGGHgjfhXjIjtfSfgp6Mzuqc9u46txSzF9je6P5@PWh2@SaVm0MIiWTu8d7Ye96/EzRYuVuMTisycrwfjy6PTxs1iYZ87nm5Reab5Jh1wbsyz10VF@pdjdxouTNcTa/L4RiBvAj6PnRjmIM7uPn11mCai@jaZjO4z52HCWK6YrDdZ3p/Sm4drIJ4s5HaNc29IjfoptXZzXWxO8otjDhGxZULavdDpojqnT2dQrj8zPaO8BxCA25WIJBxoYXjLn@VGIIWXZOFDd46Xws4Lus8nIcuZro8ab8tAp0tQrf/0w2GfPbPeUPYisCm1iD9p64MaJ6WxiTuteVpQq@tVSmH5BpNrULvwDKsFjU5Pc3iSoXeAZeCDiKm6C@Z/2lLuh5xMtfW36j5@Fya9Pe2C7uH7ft2bj6xMT2Ezm@oTeFezvIkDr@mT4vZHjkes51ycNu1O1etv8QCS2PjjleNFzPwCH7mBwfaJD370@0cOZPbVQZ1mf9JE7s9GCwLq4Q2@4Nryx22i15Kq8KRINuvsjL705Hs9FujMfdCArYp5RRumVNV0JDPtMPAzty5uO7LjpC3A/dtlX0JL8GlK8@cA2@vjupnSrGzYz3OKnN4KXzk2HeicL/dpB/sYakudDBp1jja9MuzT5d99zHe5Lb5oel@b/1pR0z7CtaxlaeOBBu@boA05oPJ6d6NdzLRAQ7m5us08W86W6uVp7mxuduBTHzQLArBL/qoWfDYyCcTMa3HiBL4efHkmlHOh86dXvvMUtMaDt99Q22j7eJqsLkPbtW7YVWDqACDG0nRDYdkATqZYzM9E4A//607S@DcXU62qhwvbww2pVpuaoTPxeZIVbogwLa7Lts8BuQbWqnrOtOhOrIgssR0SG5blxdACMZp2hUkw6Vtn2FGK2Q6sHjL7zw94yWqyVemg9F3yyErf/UgvsQgBO22dP7j85fHa0f/T8WTPXPg/sRoS1cBwoLbROc0Pvi1D5gG6gBPJPJZC9EhuKo28Q4SKvH9aL4XfNVqtWX6naslLiHubZPnMcRSHTGYp0DvhJIi@NYlGUgSAOO6wxNVBgNaXKrViQMQ5oIw5apDKh0aost67giQEKzbYTxF/8DCDF4qciq/ixSCw4sG4PPXHouv2gRN9k119hiXf37z94/vSQhQgue82p1Z@O6pUC//gBN@cD7TSw6CxxnSWDLEloq3o9eTcJhEnKSVYlYyf04QHo6JAspA6aSQly77DUNsEHCiajRlH@69eV86SMr8WkIW0yRCoJxUKfp46ytbXFjqCTsDtP739y@JQh/od3KBhJhCDYEVpa@NMf9fmne0JLaOFnMr0xaR9kSUqIW1sJTZAsraQgzWnsTjZ/LJM@lUO2SKJv9EQfGRME@oQT9NtTsqN6wcBlmmzO8Y97BvZHw4KoC4Wf@8AdWLQlinzN8i20hII4DNC052pnx0ObZFFXZvv4JVD83qhB35EC1GfOlJvPC4xoJaCnyRHPybJtQpZ/dUqMJUzubkFn75qgmDLfsWBqnFbZK@iJuMtZ5ZZyJKmRvJQlBF0ll4TKTCzhJVugvtLylPe/8s@UYY2Bewrubwfuee42@H4p8A3A/cvc/ULBjnbZdugSlzhCaHI4qAFHJKI/0j72AVSHWydaEg5NnIaMlVljaKYTojom5yXwuwT8eAkn1fwEGg26G7RYYJWIl2d67RTaPK4qCnYpXCyRaYY35/yA9gXbx8VCMa8qgKR0EgKkj5UM0fIEB5hOV2GYCCfWpP4SFPDd3V0m4oqpWS/WeMsq284LXXwZIboNaQWYUQG5JoM8kGWZA@IaQTaYfTJqGrMi90qqSWRcfRemJYrH6Qv9TkAIkaWAWJxGJn79Yo7fyp2CHhHY8O7i12VjH7LaDgBJKsxJ5EqLQmDP55E7he4Dg3T5qTpuzwdfUOBTIFqm9fkXpMl0NvZH@fLIWpqhCL@YFYw1GXkAB6XnLs6m8bYVP0UQzxBEVVzXfZsvWGvactoK75sMuukP1nRmB9y/qAw39Fle7/3LVotTF20OI7HYrWeOi0vDd6EyLKUpmq6oxfSySvn82ioFNQqKgeqgabS3UBywKWAZPdN65U78/YPD@x8/fvLskmVeSpm8mAz4fmM305LkbLMdOZLxaq02ye27yrOHt@@GDbFEuhjjxsD4g5qoV9VkueODIJdvEF6s2joML9ZuM8afchsjF/HVtatQo0yX8FBzX6BceotHukvv4l4sXCuvo1ahcBVKS3hKDPQBN6RwCdVU@uy82Qa9zEkkL/eENQPhRULewUEArpa/s61gZ79cOaxY9G33I/xiph8fi/r6sShu62j4Ee24TN3jpWnMICAWEatvWAywSEFWwqQbR99jLqQvDbhq/Nvz3GJk3B5eDOFi7iqKx0AdhZ@xRy6yND8dWF4egc5kW10htEPILTCHhmIj48vchmAqLQTfUeIFp4IP28@rc5mO7KbSyO0IVpZdZcw5hJcWYECjdPdkBrrbE3fCv6tBR7PumKHrqQvs986ML@Wa7OPZGNIN6PHUpG1y4NwSZAZKJiNUuSwFXCKw5TzPoLVsKK@JFp2DisvjfiE1T8sjc963hsDbU@kscLQbqtpmkb1nrDTZd3aSIrXZshWuHIofoXmMONm/kNHv@RIBo2nIltM356nkaTJdbUP5GJ48/fQkmRbX9SUyPh5Y4@5ftEIeoV9Sr@YkxjQYnaGJ73XcolK5zCUg7CJgbg0z/KhfpSKPfIE@0lpHyf3Z1HsAThAjUoOxMWGpmcMticqMvKlWysmSiUWpwa0UOyyTIYUKHhQhM8o5IBefv1OGs2AppY7f8YVQ3@nj4401YU1VltvgpkLSbBs/tnkAEhfa1k0LoARDliqBrWMXAjUDMOKDROYdHPJgPKSFB9ljXRNN3x6k3UQXaUK1Zo2bLPbx1FXJUaxUqkGDrnLFCoPed5kdygqAvcTnQrkeqBsYGQOagforC4klI7/M8RJUboIjci@wTgboJGKWxUOjZQxgLe1@90Ye/lKHDowVkA@q1edHdzvltCKyyMrZ0LP6uNvNv88RqXjBF9VgmCorSZM1rtF9hNnQnmyHm1FDs6Z3acCIF1hqIk6GwCZ3qCz7y76pqlf2@iBj0AqQMo8TQPA2eCcEhzaAw1WjNXHrmf1Pf5pAYSO1rarHHe8kkyzkanBTawVWYDe2W5K03czVb20boEVNX89boJMrO/kT885o0L8/VFqiyHSWV5Sds7Oz5N2dJ9aLAitKfUsrvp4vzvWi/np@rqvl18cTtdiUX8/bYrmePW63mm325Mln7zrv0uL8ZPFaZK0U6JoHj0U1LyaqFXa2V9QTxxX8yjioN8fsDVzHA4b/5H7Tj7kNdHcHoMImRZZotYDiqlgSFaWZbMM/qfsv4eKKf7MhN@S99rt36aZhTOcLZlnWxO/34eeOQILU0s8Y6Ms3gdPzDApr0ZM0KLgK4zkwu31zOJwdGgtrdnd6Sy7JZVmLrS7sPvzap8FV@/T5c8aes@fP3zzdsBbRzmRSktQk9/xCXLVjFBL4nfA//fHWefbsSWf3T78xVswtfDzGx7fPH6L7mVq4sbV14/btfD6raRp3P/nak5/f39/P38kWnjQLe3kpt7X7J3@8taVpu5qy1fZ9tZ1sHh9/Jmq5vCj/6Q@TnSdPvur7Df3/@Pq7hoq3EtxOWAn4BFw6U8GJ9zL8VJSxPvRKvElAL1cTC/rrJMLwsy2mNvZK/@27j18npomGpnzqwXOaeJ0olhPcCQ7w6aHvJNFI7GKy4nliodTrdXCW/tu/h/yNjwEOxix24dYohLCKi0RDqlOWt4lGERyqpkG5/9fXvx7DkLOJOolx4XWLNeES8yVN3GvDtUPXroDWY6WcooTpnOloarpMLd9Ub6LHAg88HBM/w2FOWwm1nGePb0HKp81MJtOWOxJc8gtaJFJUVWup6k1gB9KNnXpd2mHcPq6uF26ijf80LWkNXZgxzZufrlyJT/9errVgan8PgJ8KieLWrZd3Gg2ond7QdxoZuoIhRaOrVBZd95bIsuxlEpSRZvslqz3AqIaYK2tiNpu91eFDY45Uk@bhEEngxe@JRBSCg5ddCGvguG@zKJznYpfzsjjotekSh3j92f/6Z9/7s@/S3/fo95/Q0K7TtwbKDiQ6gcHRgOtWtdprNMSGJ5610N@AHpWrlqtlpXPeSu00G@2nTM199DZZ0JPPGM4DKpbRSrealL9BxTaC4tHfSCyDGzykEQ8LInhiCoBnQCmWWKUauSOqMXYhHUyywSsJUvOk0ZZQNKpLTbVYaEs8V/MWNI6olSpip52QthfAd7R2Qytoj9mtBr/YaNtnLmKja8WwIgG@jWXdljFLXyMelGiE2RrLNF80XYBTRUg0m0rbpJmhESJ6a6u6Va4Wq5rSaWy@assceFFS0zSf@ImTRHTVWNAPQ3omop4ZC3sRb4moWVjYgdlK3mvSQVsBi4CRwf/jlxZdjJpLL6piLXBpHZHVoH9ouqQNO2JOFaPBRgv9cG3BH/3DFXnxvkUhQTAluXxtsaq6o@lK4UbxUMOJ9porjrcAEwbrdbvdN70uiB@G0TV6hjo1ZsbcWBjT7qw77057sx7jY4Yta@/pbsEtu6FXlhJ6Qd1O3MQq6VpFK@M3GvVyWa9oeknVS0W9lNPKBb1c0Ut5vVQCgHpJ0yuVvKbpxZJeLOvFol6sQLgGaYqQRkcIpYJe0YXEu@YWe8rZWptlwquVufZ6LsudwEkOF3@S5M4TQuIf4Gqomsp2YOrLwQ3kPXKCOo5/qiqwBMhwZ@13O813OzDiG5ld4rbthhRgCQ@5c6udkc7Pm@Cu1YL/3UbkrNHFXVC59nkms/uiAaLNi0YzAyBfBCBliRFQudNg7V2KikoLigvik3k3WXRv7bZBSJIyu83duntAP5mGntQGyLsr2N66lZHBdQsANLbbLJ3JbEvSFk67zWDygbTtRiasFQBqp0AQOTv7GX@gQwL7ON89b5w3d8/Pd3fhf5fu58ETQs93L/3TY3ltSLOMbyPraTWVRktpBeynDX5ZaWCIrLTA0YAnpGvqWrmNEx6KL3L7H@e/nF3eoxBEuS0D1kJih@0k0I6sntgREi/ff/4/46/1/vPfQ1GUwZ9ZFRJnyCiUHVRkK1yfhRtzHjrsIb8ccOMv9GIIBjQeYqDDbw7udSnKS5lV@XZCSi0X0zLO6B130EHTNDJ7CUlXOCsyUSZq5aLYyagLjSV2xWKJOOjPXbqSyeQ/ealVSkm@BoS2VV76vv8whuUST0hc03KqpL5t8M@H8C89/dy665/83KZLSLytMLMK9EkxThghAf0ooSiS1BASjd0xvnyDuzASKrwn9c@k5/sSrtAYU9pj6/HVh/r9w3ql0kD1x9x@QoNm584O3FX4P9yCWrDWAJK2BvXeGETr1kAvaC381ERC6r7Gvwdv8I8d9fDv6Wv8Y0dv8O/pFP/Ywy7@Hb3Gv/0u/h2N8e/2a/x7@Ab/ng/xr/UlXVdr4vYZESajVtTz7blIBKrBhNVofWnqLar03TRR29NAXw3WsFJ6vpJOtL5kznvmZFoNFhvxTSizN60Z9UqtW9eCpMExboyRLT/8MH2wtljVWBpXQfVKwfUkPHMINwjI6BXV9ZI/@c43vpGs15NSkj55lYcwqYuJupQIvJAzzzHBTwkDftDcvp@s3Up@qUnrC4VKu4mRbYgQEnW2rW6rOTvXy6ldtQsOi@U8lhvlRmpfJT0sZ7LcIrdgubGr9sFlwl8OXFZuwHJDlnNyDiSDWHBNO7kpugbwGMLfAAB58GfhcfaumusxKMhGSZS@7qt2MGfubaclNFmSiS9NUKRlVc7JRauNHyRrii9ftpSdtlYpMxm7tdxpvmwl22JLxI9UaJU86y7MrdZLEeSNnMi7P4awhO@Ddl5LKK2WwgkP5KKWPD/vdA4f3el0FJwIWw/dx8v/x4/Hce@V/@PH7sPH7tiF/8ePH8PgNRuZWxmYIW7dqsOMETz2Eo3aXqtK80449ySU3b1WQ5fQXczAdKJhWOYLXkuI8GxstYTkKehEp6BY1VKgXp3WTmq1U3J8yr3g6KAbA6P/08ARPAlCLVLOTuE6IbDkQ@fpp63IxR3Kp6cQ9CkDpTL6B@017v17@Lf@cf0/fM7SLNVsp1Nn57sputL4l06fnZ@dB/dGOpUKPKld@MMA8GOWs/MGOinRGbiaqXQ7fX7Ow@CeSu9ygA0oZrdBeZfpYGJKREVSsfyW@vt9QtHB1UrWGDBCWjgo5GgcJcQaM5aHhlqteS6XBj4XfH8Ht8CNt3QyI12jj69ud5tq@09@SN9Y2ktTokK@VlN3GPdoea1Wy4e@UrlWK4ee7VSqcvlq5PbUIuhU@Xw6XauBZy8EmwMv5G2ydxlWZy24t2/e5IWUtbdvQ5h6vpjJ4WGtWi0sqQDFmr7RC5j@2f3H9HkiYDWFBH4XjLOSVI4@boYTQVKsijdvpvomvjPR39tP37ypVXJv30YhkwkEqStBnU7f8jodDNffvhU7Ih3yqRTAnyu/favmKhk1mXa91CP88ioUlZJUdkNrUKkVYPJavgTRAQKF3d1ivtEo5iGkWE6m8cAAZ/GAb1JM1sTEGdVBLZc4BxRrGBxpYjCQfZxoz84T1JosX0ingIumQQQ9T@CfhwyXT3SFQrqWz@USZ@ciT6xWKjx1muWLqXKmEvzVt9KsAWIW/0NZUc/kd0o7t0Daxj9/vu5Cnlw7M@vqef3MrOKWwXkNRAXfBSEJTfyYN2/qFSBROVdrCZ3Onf2j/U6nDnMZimpww0Di7gJaPvKS1dotale1XGDQgDxQSsKUwMpAZUXbKahlpIpgDdBkF5BB4CrfFtsSNHriTahwam1BIGhQUFofLtZnXTbEiw1RA2UWs@liNuPxdO/1okQuv4LYyEt5SUkNQ8zoEoJhp/M@CbP2kwf7B4dHWW1XYgnt7v5BVnv2/HZCRW9h6adoHf1PD/fvPH4OGZ48ONx/dvjR/U8Onz@BcJ@dLq@Qywf35TPuWuM/ZZ8Kr7w3hmka5sw0O6ez2elr9sqyOha0nj2DSrlDj/lmB@oyMZb1qsGvZ/nGq1eGN6GLvf/Bt97/4L97/9vfef/b33r/29/7yeff@xb8fgS/7/Dnd/5dpYD3n3z@L37n/W/9NgT@J/j9Ifx@/JPPf/3r/Ef@P4Lff4mF/VHwi6XjPwFg/dJPPv/uD3/y@S9/H37/Kvh9//LvV368/ve9b27@Yb7v/s7Vab7z7@H3uxxWmPY7v8XD8Hkp/W/xdL/8/fe/9h/4/58Ef@j87fe/9kd4Czz//Pt/8l/ef@M/alr5T/7t@29@9/03v/H@m99@/81/qr3/9X@r5uK333n/vd//yz/43b/8g/@R/n9E99/9kP/33//nf/6//Pn/9ud/EPx@DL//AK4f//l/hKHyN7//A/z/7u//zR/@AP//p3/9N7//q3/zS/@GHL/BHf/3v/p3/P5Xv/Kf//o3v/2XP/76X//qj//6N37/L//3X/4/f/0//9V//3t/9c@@gYG/8eO//MNf@otvfOsvvvkv/@Ibn2@4f@vK@@cfEP75P0DIh@P5IXA@pF5fNOTznwmfvws1lqVAP4He/Yvvf/0XoIP/GmPvv/UjfBsWfhv@f6SplOZH3Pf/A4d2uc4YkwMX/H71/be@gyT6H4BE8B/R69uRZyWGe7699ABZf3NNpl/8yef/8ofkS5jVBu1B4WRd1sqZHVBodiqVYMIOtqcgyy@sQosABCV9GznUSty3kbe9/8HX3//wn77/wW@8/8Ev4Wwt5SvZ/aykXrO3BwkLH5AOExY/JB0m/AzK72RoUU/KfAa@rc8KZd1xnNpnn30mdN4q@Nr1rbfsM/hjn4UX41H4WnYQFcZhOL6nzSC8@fJlGzeEY2GKyoErGn8GUXheH0qStBuZPUXVeJT5VtnmuVgNAvSy3oqhrgwGO1X4Y3CrVnfOstJeC4Q@ynoumGGV1ADqlsJUI6vv6AYkVPI8Has6t3L5TGnHMEAFziDcDMk8O6EMVtDZPBMUOQ82jTEcEs13yDlnfCdgTtFzYU57y/BfYqzMdMYc/l8TWIYWyunCz9OGTnIE@cJ9aXIKBSgms9xnIKGQcalsh4fQbjuVm68wrMF8npmDtg0OKCEDUbdB7q/XM5ixzlEEL69Mo8wIlUymDvXG3DxPtlNGEPPbBAVy1jNPWWenPucZMwivEZIjI2DQU1HVxEy5fgcKrM/vMISFwAnsy5f1Rrk@byC4d5w6mXnmNuGEwOqZeeMd@OsEE/IJiTvvAJVyPZNplLFArCRvnmyHN1KBKkd1z7BM0AbwxJcm9m4xdkNUyyLfYtlCgvHUeM8sU2NCSA7xrcxOUB36D5302yGCb1FRQSmMx@@RTLzHxWRMAHAlSZZlBj88xbDHbkH0nIPKULHwyHAIGeoR1AOiAIYLURkhQ@2bIQ@Un6jvfOELgWFltre3hURD1MXHMpFOUZh3XKU3SPBQJaoyVSYWKyIGm/Q6TYgL5K9R@dtJ3JRMMg6Y3cjw361bO@wGVJOeyzCBSRndzbsJDmU3kxE1gN9wM8IL0H8E6KcE6K0gz@u0CZoRslnG5HoC49jjx48DJCjgRV3IQDfXdBX9uBc3m80SkEOWs3I2GzxlelKAHDhkig2e8jYS99SzpibTtHwN1LQawyAW16lU0LUx8N27d9AqdEqteh@0XBYcWNPyZYqEAG71yrYX4XtXWr4i8CUAphbzjKVoNRmuNMMXjFLQkdICf7uBoxFeqaRWLicpJdBfTu2EJxiLKnIA/iYXvQTNCqUVL2AT9@KyIF97xp346BUqjl@qXEiHkQeP2cHjhw8PHx1N2m0m4CdwZ1OzM/Hcnun7KYzbf3SHvwijVYrpRLOJVDmqasiRhMNqDjtq5v6dp/efVRmnUtBmKapHjTaxA7pUVCExmXy6mwgOfIn4HVNXfIb36pIUKa0C3DKdaAiJnokqEHQ@/IdfTXjoD2@7c5bKZUUxqxZRBU3jZizg8fPujKGVbW6SCwYhvh4j7@4SBYTGmRTb/MGABnuqCdwhqeRgeqUcOkrcoZaKmIAfqmS60Hh2eASgjx4zVcvJQuMzNpcRNelcaNh123SG09E2nk4UWzkxVvvtZi6Lf5quw13NF7NqodTe2rLPJCyoRf3hDI@ZnoP3TMIKfxkuJnxZYF@GILigDDw7yoK19PuPa8HpSbR8meJHKEW1ACM4LeB@AAcnTOJXDQbO6naakNj62temrNE4fHRHun9XSAAjGrHwAKFk9eWRTB2iP/NMih0y1rc@sfBTtnLf8ie2sYBRCdRInJ@fDwDS/btMa2jk5Tn6eD/vUUgX3OdzQ0g41Wr9nZovCU/3q9V3uqYJECDsKHhCcQu6Ch3v2FH4X82HQnS9rAATVEURHrquC9TRhaopMDrM8y5Xr0u8t@p5lc7yCPh1JGNeX@7KB2nnN5Zp9RxPizEQwYZTj@XCuBKPC3xFgXxANDy@iEfRhVow7nM3b@q4EKPnc9GKC9WYnUPbbOt5HSmOr4e1E/lSsNUkimI7IdjmlPXr4E604MYXFTU1ITL0IT/Syzkh0UzA6BOa7Wb9//2/dlNoz//x/gNZms26MAcmFv8FwZiGnmzlT/j/6BXsKO5OGnpO3VUm4DTAmd9VDHB2wVnYVbrgtMBZ2VUscM4auprbVWYNoMkuNxzO0C5ZXZyac/xOAQ8TG75pD2R8c64uUgGauBt8iKMRZmz06323N8OjSrW@bDmO6aEVEZ4hnxdrroMmbevhRh6w9PSZMKyfkq0TwawPZbSS5jmGLfTlrttfyP50YeM7aLbr1ZOgBiTDiCV0E@RDXPzc0/V8tcna8sSd7AlaoZRpqjmY2PGnlrNadsvcK5Wqfblnm4a3V6gWytk@vt4WbLPuFXLVofzZwwf3ptPJU5PeedvLVyAD2hVFC4B75WqhAB1GFDNNKqbdzLVlztulrS1giKbRl@CJu7C@pJXbkLlvefV6Mrmnq5qkVvVc@VxYEg5pjjVsCJg1gzXLIt3PAvZZdVwHOHU1a2StM6JCdTAYnO@cZZYewTiTuA/ocy4Z2e5Z5K1JsXRVNstK1jISQowBkPss2F@uilqhLNaataW/VBRr7XPh1tjsWwa@6tbKnV3OVYQZjUNNQEEtJpxXPdedVrvmwPXMZUJdLYYJOUKXE@TF86i4Vg5LPLtcXDGWaH52GUq@IJ5HuUK0hPNzoDsnNpA9sArfoCPhTbWSbx8C/4busxsajMdkiRcvhMTO00/0RgOa@ixf0vKFfEHTi8VCSYPJupIvgjKcU3PFXEHTAEq@Uq6UzqFfK8q7BH0Plh2chf29Sl/ESRlVbtK52Wbpd48s@6ysSxyPVLoGs0LinZC48fQTrdHYrJinQLj5RJMadb1QAZeOLk0XkLNpmqTpkq5Kqo7/1zg0/P/w9Br8a3iHXLomHKGht0cgdIBI5bAHaDBq6rIjFz8ZOGS3zd6GFAcjgw7sH3iu7/8d0tw2nGMedcfi1tWjqHsGfjfVH1vT0YYUzydjtBFnev9gEA7HXUAQ@SFPcBtunu266xKU2PMnG2r5MPqeCRCDf9AEkj@9/9G9o9jz6HD/4J5QZLcfP7pz4VEIEhXYg8O7R5G3xGPDrIUIxM8fPnhw0Rs88o@fPx3MXA9/wt3Hz/PLWxSE74MLebhWE0XBBCS4oZcEeJDHQEMulEKHKuBbRDfzFXYzcBaKS2cOnZ/yl90tP3qrhds9qApH4RvwBkNW2zVZj5sCxGUUMtMbqFhqqSIIE@a4p6yUY33Xtg2PuYPBFgSODHyb10TFwbaxJ2LRp65n90@tvrklPMQXhyugfw0ICeEeABnPemRlBkRBNPoO05rDcGOya89MNpuwjYHwwCB0etZwBJPwqRsmELqGweD3RS/Ib8av6dUBU14GhV2KsS8nF0DZLhdE8UAU7xlTo1PzzNKLXLX6xIPZ2PCHZuNwDh0Who/hLbLlrC5Oxbus6rzY0Ya4z2W7E1T0/EkT9B3QVPdaf/WbP/rbP/7VYV1r5Q5yBVyh2917@CCvLQwuCKtKrVt/B9rzuPu28YLt5V2Ypm8xVqgC3wMFgZEOEOgJMumWWqVcKFd0rZwtV8r5glosFLKqlgU9vlQBfSunltViuVBRs@V8BWSUfAViC6DkcS1DCdUKZacKYJ2ePeubu6SeyiPQQ/kuNXuTMtIsYUT@GRNNyCMKuHQwJbMJO1Ydplem5pheYgDRYD2WuHv3IHf3rijeRg@e8jnIiWIfPYVyLle6LYomxRyUUd4SXZ6njHZ2xSn35HK3gf4zDgA/USOKI/QcFnHxVRQt9Bzs372L5QzQo2F@SHbMY7jHDj0lSOagB5QfAvA6ggbJ9nk5eUL0ED1YJMbc5TEHECeKH4XoYMxTnowDuBfWdH9fFO9zz/4@xhxQtQsc0a@gZ58uUfTAA@NCFIfgGHowIkWxC04cHaLYA1dvYUDYGFz4FRNnaojigpMHCSSKc0pt9I5FsROGYzGfBNgUkLpV8qi81rfIU8E/UdRCpDGZHnl0UcxHnjzU7d69T4zRtG8O@bXw@LMHNb13Tzes@ezwbvejj7rDYddb7B9@9BSjDg7ugayymHndYTfI2O3A5UKug3uacTxeXLyg1vc7naphr436SqeTN5wLUZ1Fx0QMIddrwCy4hljQuHMAUQf3OreMdacMCGAHGcMYnl28bo/hedvo8qjwoih6zrtdsYbdX1FaKQG1CTwugMPxGBitkx0bPc@toX9eZ7ksyjOLZjHXrlEEG4NWkKudY/wghXcDV@zSZ4vmvJ5r1@f1UnA@cJASW3OtYInZrfGeWilUt4w9Vctn5lW03OIOkiwpqXsspd7cecNSj9J7GmgIYmtvTxKbantPU8vVYunFzkwU01W87@ml6ptULpljDG/pZqm9VyrEcpRKGUPRqqUSyGlAkynM9l1cF@ukUqemcZxOI7a09gJVoLqyBdXTqg1S8@y8zvFii3RtXldr3Ho/y10C1sdPxcx6U9fjIIcAbr6Xq@LRlJSoVsoiIKAoqXQ6YnoKuJbLWJ9@9ej46OgzkgcbwbLQE89E7lULvB/dO5DvPw59@JEX@S7Kqa4nHyDXWonhAmsYdAQainwPZljQ9sIwfEPWc235kI51grAbRoR25uTA4Lp8dG8FzrORe8pLRgMjNbLa6/RMht/AsfrMqDfAZfRZirBiRvqU5vZOo1Hv1MdkgwOqGOb6CqMPxCzB3Pc57pHZE8p@hm@NBhGdeu4cppV5Yg5wOnUmqS/Hbv@llunV@vjpm9v125i51oFnt2bWTc9zPRF0bbE22HPqM8c3BuYT00ODPvcfb4Okga@SpgbMTG@z1iGmPkA95lxqeMxZYvZoNk4ZUqObXg3CxdEoAImT@mpY6TN6u7lTF8Xz2qDOUi8g6Wvwe9ss1Zdvp/fyNaDTbdZJQ1Du5eDlgGmsmK@RHpJCWDCUiD5Yb4Ol642vwIPDPq5WAZugoY8BKhYGgK0@RUDqiXVe69VtlpLYnKWJSPnasN7E7G/xtiuJYluSmm/bQkOSPhUaMF5ri4RR92dd@moay3VVLVeszSFMLeVrI2he48W85tUnM8@s2eANVkr5i9xGDYgKtAMwb96m3v/C19O7UqHOw2oE6i0KBh25U5/XHLTDDB2jrtchItPM57Kg4cOtlIU5Xytm1WJWz@azUglDYcLPFrIQCAoQiB8pOyUyJmZz85ysZlVTzaZyL63@y3T2OAUiDRGNpbNT99CZjRmEQFNh3yQvPIE8GW3HBsWs7zJjV6LOCiyjhhUDqo/YxMqOENRT07ApRzotMX0nZW@nMM320Wxy2GxXq4fzyVchKiW93itmSrnMm3S6ltpK133ztdCoCQ1kL1TryRb03GARmfmzcRNaGVxqSas2m12sYimX1XM61M7qvB3uig2xnc1tFVVoonNGbINxvhFfV0WJZxk26aBgbpvQdGpFqwkyLXLqZU2qKIWdQo4vtPKcwiRgb0hJlmqJodGCVDJZ0pLJdLKGu0dbYrD6DzyN@FkSuGvyprongjAmVsWKhgmWrJHeS8@F2IE4di6gzMjyoPeeCedn57sN4UvCM3zbeFd7gX@lFw/3H@PflyCoAt7yi4fPHz9/fFdgCp0EljuJ2lZNrnVq4JHkxi0hUWUMOGkrsKimbDH2Rc8YZ3YbL/izha@3AFyBvq3QZG06@2daqNSxT9Baxx5LQh0Mb9zUNL3d1Eow9wE3DZNqmloDLDoJfH9GbkBjzM8Av91MA190/QpbLIyMFK4E3Kw2hpntnLZInHTEYkXn72k21Nwx20re3GEgzkgscXK81dB2MsknVT2TvJPU84mTVGu7kVEXSYXtZLTFAI8w4Fa4koR0mrlzQ99JPs9Uy8NsVc3gXYN7NcmkrcStTvZWuuIL1CQscWFpYr@@P3y6Hx6Z3D9olLVF8IJu4kVHLJcCFFvbQDIt82I1dwMm3xe4F9ES8O2LZOIsyRLJc/gTErfoJWCNvwTMEtFrwHiEINhY0/NFlk5U0oGvVEn4qWhX60vJW4kkbh5Vff9dgrpU@GblV15q0JsTjhsGgK6HC3Ew2xYKuG@SUF5O/K9pZf3h/cfOHe@uKSRaW2@3XNzvYrUI/XfOx19lbAIETrJWPTGv54NXGdRGQ1J3NTR7WGJVmFAGalHKvW3wIdOgiKIGMe9/4fv5@S5oQ0zLqeDXtEJGazTUHQ0qNnn/@e@hAauzw0/2H7Ak7n387R//UCv97R//azrxmDyn/RBNLyUgJTrVYilxdjY5OzuHi8cVEu3EpYMebaCPohqV0o4MtVHKBjg6SoLTEUSokppO@FIiONlaLEiplKpo6R29nEtDzNvAQF1Ky5XBG24eUpBYLIjpxOFTq6Cpt3b3oGZ7el6rbUFbqtEL3Sz62zX9CmqWD1@@ZQw8vUZ/OLQ0cikKq76Tdt8xaZe9w327d9IWe1lv4EEVFV8DD3erdvD1UtwMTjYyyk6SgerFGs3z2nk7Q9tdpMG@2HFaF@jQ2sKXl1aDdhz4M3d8@jNN8lKAD97QZ@688sXUTlpR@n3x8nrdrskKDegqOwpguRNuXvE/SWql3//Cr2ta8W//@Ffedt52PtNAba1UiqqW@OlPd2fOzDf7jZ9CxivMFYWqJ0mfaFcIHZHKyri1ZyvIFTnkHmjLMwfFc54@VGBRZWUg2lhDx@yTAiucoDhGLdrhFjP7KUq2g9ZMsiTek4W6dE0QQjmYi@/esJclGGwHTZQ322nhTPgyRsFsz0AFqAlfXoKCgDHM726v49szb0IvfaUon9rOspuQBUr4Mloj3SIrLMFUIQHPVHYuZ@Uo@0Q1Et3Y2PR9tG0Ks5zwZcgSfMfBXrCJgQaDMKXlwNwkYxLCkyL6TSi7DWXbPEOHQlNUe54gyzh2PJMDIr7wZZBWiAoWCDHM2oUENWAnXwYCQB1SAWCrzXaZnmZnViZTWxpOPceXQ/AlKCM0ViJgNoTWR@M4YeYapoMgUC3wy@HYL4IWBhkyFhgC4TD4EY86KCeYnXwoF5I1oQ8GBbDIcl@KqsZu3lxiVa9b/TSjGiH8Y2uC627UDs56XAFYqNjd6FfFLEOTtLUwNOp2QPEMoQu9TuK2aGuxrExE77kgwP8Hd1rskReaiiJqWIGgvfio6AHJIDOSnbdhj@3WmaqV0ixCvge49wgpMhkRaaut@Q1Z@yyMPAcMf5oIv8sHzOoovpYZ9NuL1moYyPIz/Cga2izkzCCwMsOtEiLTuz8Nc0e5oCqWTakHlgd6FJ09CQ2ipnQ1jdmWBmQJD3p9Q8szfIuikMYH5cLUDJ4GGvYMytkig2Q9FxrUn7gOWQIlS2X4Cgv0COBRgRFFjvbMOcWPaAZtQ5njGPlkQBF7PmJMlk1dNPlEefEsR9cDfTukTZaZQ5n1xn2mVViKOhoZe3QicGnKRAh3QRxHGndtcwwoPTNNevXSryrKEES0WZcsXj60oF@N7low8zi@cocTWDm1ji3lCK3ZS@4A39Dk9oMSKNXh8OOHQQLrkrbrHjPbOjb5EnVqxfqSz0AhAZk6C5Rd/oCwVTzApOlZXBdRszwV/ErwKHFnORvLu5VapC8/dXUr1cEWfUuTjwWtYpsnhhOjL11vhUAT9xd@aL@NrJCBX45YrhlYbqon0SZLZJJMCCzR1ckImoxbH5OUmBBDC27oFCaeecJQpxZwjgGm2QttIeEohtp@mSYAGnswstCw69SrogUvwMTrp3ow9AIG77AbTNcETMjN6wWm8AAGNn19FTrEQVashz/tQ8PItN6PfAVG57gPcWg7Juh@mD/s3egmo7vL7s22AnA46VBZdcaHRegpxDw4OrA/U9W3ILIIGK7BZCslZgBsRkyLHHSU/2J23tsF4iVVdhlSliGEgNQAhUQFA1kOWu6Mfe1SgIjbhs8/iRSYfT09PZXJFvHMs2TTxy9A@q5j2MpkaIEk7CpTczxRTB@Grmf1lEkId@mS@Idf5closjdHebZeubngT0EY@PXgVFcqOfCTODme4AcOh2OyW4gGA33qUHct@jhqLxUcMuP9T2tnz8L@V8X@J5WT5wiEMQQzzy6yvSwAy3Z7x9nBab8WRJzQgATg0IpmGIgWwr3QM/ZDlzUZRCncKfLRKKprH9MOMkAS@QLysmhewzDlIvQG/ok1h0yOecr2Pc9YpCg@jamxA6cWJPawBUz7FANO/FzEGTdXbc2bi/ZK9nmUHSa16PyEh0YJhbOrgXLb5Rg/5/FziJ/z@Pmy0LDY5rzNRTIMOsfqYK9HW7ZhSgSzCNOcczvfyxiCDHI4UzkITLlYCTuHX69OuUN6cx@0Yz3sGNAnJkBwM6U0X7Sarbbjm6c77YwyhM4uEiGgxQF0s000Pe1HbqS@fWJPXH8lyEETxjArBXhjUG8U9AbeV7COUQNRx@D0stDq7HAcHPTgAkFQYYCAchhEomiwP01Z6VpkLJ8ioeM0xSWNOWLNAJk2SV9BVBAG4hInPSdsHFA7BgjDoyoBmhDDwpHDv/cbcodPPRfShGkl@kTpGK0fJttJoOSFocJ5TY0aKYaVJIVoAtlRXK1frEoYD03RvBAVq@Z50P5x9Le@MPoDGBfrsacOyyeMmhAfKniEFUSIYLgQVVmjHmtXwEDZMWzTg5nrkMunwWwNxewooZrBy8Eq@KfWtDdKxRq/l@btQ6/wio5YjbrCol6HKi7qfFjycRGSlBM8yuYH2RZhRwjycwYCMHJrs5lBtnk827xe54yDzTdkO40hOSck5zwLTz3fgGQ7yPb/dPd9623jyJ7X5lMgstMmY@qfkziJHLkj23Ki6cTOsZ1kso5bTUuUzY4sqUX5jzrJfGf3Yl9g934fYV/lvMO52qeYrV8VQIKSLDvdc87stz0TiySAQqFQKBSAQhWtnhpmekH3HJN2ChvbHMEryzRKatAgp@LgMsRp/K/wzIpDC11nKnOYCzQPQcUGn7WOZ9Z@ZCFtCa0JAGDEKQCkhQQX3VHFmRR45XzylsgoIaWRUfKm2UBkBTEYi@B18V7uJkzGa2BS@HMrPA/Q2M2tHDm5Mm88438l@ZfzzUfzrzz9sZTNWc5@LPkT//sP@XgMyloD1NI@yqVHEMhYybzrabe/ts6xqGoXtMAhre7kqq/cGco2fS9e6KLFk27/pHgewKoGAcXla2Ew9sz6AUc36sWgPwpG/UePKrJoipjtZtUva4botNdHHEIrggHpeu1@GPeWR9Sprf5pL4pDX8G57OdQLztCHVPFsfVk/diPHUcbeMkyFqCFr6DqNptRLxo1my7sJr1KYmvPZpRgz@VlB@tferLKk3jSQPcGbv/k17A18m6HiXAcuthh1Prs7g10IvyW1BTJsBbp/5R6RhqMivvpypFd/UOVPhm5HH3mrH/ePyWt7yIuYP/VmQDfSGEDoWAwYFx8FWBJW7GCsvAocVt@4OmiP313UfXTqht4SfnVLIAMMXw1nKQxKDucUV3zxuqkmKnv4PvxPbDxPZiPL6/CJ3GWpXlVEr@v6oduCoEypmg8vB0NNJ3kVnsKnQwqyWfoVVLgzii22WqtDUxrlLWmsxc6xB9@8hbTW4L4@5voP78DTfH6XbsvoGGvDsYkb85hASo@h2JzAutS9oYH2TNdXcLa23esi/IiavcOVAhSY1lw9eClnAYm4nzFycaxAXwLz8NQbIrv2XqsKokzcBpe@urz6s1dtN1sh91gHLZdndO34JoW79OCjeXV3RoOQcdCry9rPZfmLi9JpWkcRJdMlRtYJvAvPe9mtpIsUcI9vFPOGDZuph/Sp0QztviqsltN64Dl5UVsx15G2P5EfDMJhNGVuKFajsr8Iz0JNyS3E4ToILNn2U@r9eaJz303adIdZoQkbyHbZPipNxDhYGy6D7@PRLe3lDrXKlQ1vexkQ0DN7vFoXo9bXGF4Uo6b7saStzHdnXnOYjUBloqwre@bQqYgw2yk1XJtiPJlbo/1e1MyAd94n653w6zSnCFQk5Is6UYRL7dZv/AcrIwb9IsNp/f0C4Cn4agpDGXahj0tHYpbccp5MLC0Fv2FlHSCYlFRSK7RsHI55pmyf/mW1Nm6sc7WVJ2tTJ3JCMhWaWVyWpkqdS@ge@Z1QTfsjG6QzkjC2pl@5olt@q/XD4bYrfiyHC1XIl8tXy5XSCAvh8uVuktCebm9XNnmh3i5csAPn5crP9FDOraWvy5XzLBAhiG98sMLfNciHO@t5cqW631zRsHnMDb1FpYrSZ9Snh/llSlCpEC7SWvEEVuvr5s5GoY0sbFS6StwTOxj@cT7MD7/K9H/Jagbh3tCIvY4H3BmtaLKmUnDmjGkHpo2TDiRGSO5omfz@t4Om10lWVDNCq3x7DIMntTwxeWsMBLEkMonGvRLCEJuVmZjpKyZ7I7o6NqJQ7mTs/VLfE3WB9oupx9R5uO0Eo7kp8ub/sqCkA68G54ofBOeU@iY6hgjnMl6M9ACUX9ZntMo9HUWF937dg/xXnc2E2GbN1mklxisJdNJh@PDOY5Q2h9kmYRTYfsf2WV4U04GJbh3ohhLBT0yb0jmz7plEAz24PfmNccqB9QyIgiJR6VjGWXJvMCyGEmprLM0VRl8hIIlc2iEh63PHCVxWz9yPhE3Ps8VN01DpqxUyZIrKyapcAFu1S6CkdSeLF7rcLb2fctXU/Iaey0uAFglk1pEvva/Q3/vi/5uFGpDhIkKZinWs6fSafV67iw7gXk3rXa6A5Hoq21vpnKU1JCSnFYHlmY@j9emVHyYfIiSL5Um0Ce0fUO2ZE1wC90m1xYCC1rC8DL78fMqffy8ejOhpjWS7mXBKC0F1KThSMMTTNOmzcdVGj6ri5HC@9tB97s7eJjtYLvzAI8bMJwguYzy4UWPrVzSsU1iW75ApJYrSgQ5H5cm3Zx@JHHPR7fJsS192Gvub@/tvv5Ik@6TJ088PUePU/wwarHXmszjApltuJP5YMayZdVHKDMcdmM7Pj7rD0f3PvVyU7JEhDUpAwHVYthPj3FPyzJLnk@MXSoneS2Kalif02EQZKQSVJ0AU3ak6ToigoQj90GggRj1lujt82rN46BdzWYvOA@bTZ6@mk0YLzWbehZD15gTce/vi/eKF/GweBL1ihJx7spx2O2I2t5TH17VDtXhq7raebf1k/q49059qO0ewi3E23ebrxtbiv7Vdw/qysmY4CE6JxaURNftsBVyVOfVUumRYshb/cFY5I675cn3g@Bcveq3QhxTPY@D8xdn8lLohaMNKVWn5egYe5gRR2M9j0awt@DwobSMhXLT5vuKuHSgKO8JrWnPseY977ejTkR5Hax9B1EYmytuqhtRD5K8Nde8fVGSECmUTYc4AjAssK6oeED5cXZDYAKxvwKJkUNCi7YLShMu@e@7KXhY339zoOCLZGtvd7tx2NjbPVA7e/v0@vZjY/cl0bNxcLjf2HyHJM74Zm@7sdPYqvEHQaBUUHAS8utFPJqLQgHZmSqtzzj5Lgyo@5O37K43NHh1FfDNzVgtX/QgfaKgG/0etpfXnYsY6gtui/JRgXKXavsv39Ocr8LfcMJpjoLZ/iD3LubotUsl9Zxro8GyQeNtXQ9XmvbyZY/PI87HCgGswnV2CeLys68McDbiaUehym3BRgV73@I5hMeyAU0V3SPYAGUMVqqKA88tL/vPGeQG1dbq9uGqVmoTI0L9gqIvjKnJusMU07YyAIprFY0e9oPK68kH4nv6sKqrHQ0lg3qYfJAM6pF8gCragO2IeqxzXIz2LiCe1Zp8@PV8sMPHwupJ8mEz4FXsU42T9Bt3aaCSwJ3wo9Ll8IKyy8MhkMWBDorEnB@h97pdGRihBH0lmShHiWzbRjlzJGw6OGrQZm8STB2pxA2wEwo6o1i5Va@gDmEcFPYiCex42g16YgKVmu4w76mn8IZV1RfDoyQgIl9UGfSZARGMNYtHUm5ba4XhXctRyc2pGgNtI8lBiY0J2m0IbE4h8EfAEKB8ZqXT4pmKL9MCTL@jWdmN@8SR2Lf9m52f2Ll90QozBbTVlvtr9Pvvniayn1knGTtFxo666PdwSGolH2V2@kMa4yxWOYQcpGDrrD8YRdKHbrYFfOLE0xzlxsRGtf1S3cjUBjpM1tjr96xKT4iLb6j1hJjyLrUyx8vZeSK@0tjixPk0CYvdHdAJTvqXoXV25uMQ6SrE9gspwnxWjs3P8YgxEf3TSWXH3xRCEj@tbmxvfsr/7RcfcYlFLEhYcGN0iH/EmKiLhgef87HB4hB6lx5pJp5kfHGC0toGT0tLjHIDjNaBZxGt614015M0MTee/o5LPJPf@ePXr1UplYdk0rHk4zM3lW6@OjJV@lzmWGkTEEt2ErIk613zxWeYibx@gYs76AX4YOpBjmDdPhGtUYsQ07qTiw5JFh00W3d3At9TG2xRYRRJ8Rhh90fxZ3ezurLhFVODEmWR0zUi2jeQy55nmaXwfDUFbns@OJLfdwf3dC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7f8ys2wZFqyYN0d7N/mgJXJ7Q@Bpbb7NwOWSXIaWsLpCXP6S4uJNe38Gn@Z6jseewQGcy92UBKgVm0XPT6iNo7fXSng2WBShejgcLu@v69ysj6hsiT3sGRoazEI2PfU29TaNuqxsCskSlOyWE6UJ/MlY9Fm/ps3mGcS7wZRoXUQX9MjERbJPRxa0F2L1NMzC6sQbH3PAtFQLovdFyOD4iMN@ButAQnZtNOsBjozm7kok08U20bgmm6@6Ma2DT9bWMvcjVDUw7ENyLYJCk5xs2R2/30Q/bhi6hEFC76X0OA2adI039A64YAqHlDGQiHbg3O6xXQpjOxFwV40tIPhVymrYf95hmJGEiVcdGFLrGvlWKMm@vGSUXPYIBHTQABLT50oFs2UYEQ8f3lud6iXTnpudgoiJRPBiV/YXEHFj7/pKYypkcyT1UQht8faEmNzZLA8xu6shr1@c6b7sIVemxQPk1WRtJ1bVf4fU5XMEpmaDM1nNsYkEuS1x48f3gZ7shWmeP7PwpY5ZFJ@js4HtL5PQcbjmLf3iXMbu75JTxlgDunEtN4MmImCpOrMmFMybefJyMaPcJF9IUIGwRMQ73myVk9dT@A2G7rMSDZ0zjLVBmsIJw2VUTNF/W/zq4NAvrW@e99fnww2ZILp4DdY5b/pD@MwvZVneZKxPuEGfvZbOBz2OJvcZzoHFJevMc29bMe37cTgVVqFRD5vs1vS0beTxOzWN3sNXAlvLxYQ4h27e@uT23v58rrd1J3G67p6wJ5HO5m9yNww51my517Um4cAy2Del8D0wXf47scV@kc4@AYkkYlv87lMG@9W3JgipDUfcTgtbRaqZWt5svc7cSvowfeIn7sfq5z/AxXkXdj63o43a2e9tJ4pT8jFg55LpfxcvpDjovQNG7qAlAUhvYnv1oSFmxrGUhLXa077sI/CwVZ4LbtnbDkZFMtPS2vPHG5dzx/550fPjv0HrWpO0eQb9M7ji@FV@/Np/@yyo7pq8OvJdWv8@29KPX4Ez@Nq9QfxLF1eqxbZN@8TBafkz0rMuRrBH9lLNkKOFyQWs1LLKl2Hr99THj/wormCGxITXKoenBsuxBW7UfX8aO242quW1s@PesfruOQ3WqmOVsorLj78QLMoyRg5mT8aHWNOtXddw96lgpNVjvSrr4YovhpCX94Ew6j/urb7MrMbBwUAW2Da1ps31CW8@wKs2XD3pNALr1y9TeYrcKwDBclZ4FtBZVx25/1kbMe0I8KMesUnbTa@5r9jz1koFS4Goz6nGK@QYC31NfrqLJhrTCXeUaAsR5HxHYn7BQQnzePiYEi@jsWKOl8Wda2Mu5OeBeIIJVkc5j7lcrhTCET1Xa6jYycuhEHrDEh0Sa3@ysXU8@cKb8RqcYF38WDKEQz5wkTpGI84AKGfAZ82oArW3GO@9uFQ8/FexoN84T2qEd@TYQN5hzVFpMD8W33h@01c/jkRQAi/IDpXQW9xas2LFEm5O8ibC/C4ll3445gB1yqlUxbQWMCW@qopcLYUZxqhWk0m@r5wBXIKreg/3YJ8md@mmpHk9yQ7k4TPqfVbDFpyl3LSBn66aTHXKpY3xUxmixQLt1IDO120PHoT0rAaq62w2yWkhRYLKTnwyPd7df0rSf3xEeo8TpCX9PxUej6TXpB0QSrNVaAJPs1UsTPlFr@k@b6pXJrNn6qrqlh5KVBPtwqkkqR51@fljQujfjNKM28kXSlcmSQ8zyTkrZSfZ/S@pNzLlEkYPEk/knTN36u65xMsM3lfZOvHr6M7KGTjWW1rMsGlhV7U/VEmrSQFbJYjaiolxTkOqTKDqqrvYGpxQhoc9vl52G5UUygrZSNxeMzkNp6/yBW0kvGjO4mG3GKcGlgzxohFJa5zhQl3zRcWqR5OvmeBYJhgNGVG7oYpPNaFxxZY5LpnqpVbkFMDnJo2OcSruBf5FX/MYM8iZ/Itzk5cEMyvpfFyuzlLIBa693KzyZSVJrguIh91o@bMImnd40mIs4XErrULnNQZyh3sDrbB7yVywhYURlJM0T1J0ZROM5QN@97UhUj85vy9@MB5GZCOPeiG16qGZUbAt7CczAX3URiPYnifYsc48cVg0MWpIyt8V3yFWgdLWH2M45YUojWzF5wGLHskv48nfSGdChXUHiBfwUAkTYgvTk9xmQw3YPtXEK3YcYlGBafWG8uGBo2Zh6tyzTxUcL7BArgbndpISM/J6AGl40HQCgsO6WgxaT@ONLUT6fC9vJ@OeyNwckZTWsVx/uUian3eeonz3Cfl0sOyRbJLfRxcKjx8lF6wIiKZhFX4KXxcfuQ41tlwS86G8wDoq9eY6N8Tb4aXYa8XOjWaMThjTEprHA4vw3bBcfbD5BAYcMHKOJnEPez@xbAlmzukdAXEjLglHPtyHEYchl/Mz3Jc3OKzMt/BoVV62kxdfRm1QUBz46TTx@kwH1jATYDQA4XOwxER5YGnsijx2bPGhXWXc2xEETXg58Q6m0jI0OuPohb1DO9kOV0CJccgaWW99gQmVF@rG@BycGEWArgek1LAIGCOkubh4OhD8@/CQemGmTP2wPRMkaRfn8cKDfdwGJH0TQnMvcLFLNypgw9fNQ7Uwd7O4Yfafl3R89v9vfeN7fq22vzIZ9w4KGd3wOrV3muSLslpupya79GHXO2ASuY4wantflT1v77drx8cqL191Xjz9nWDoBH4/druYaN@4KvG7tbrd9t8@k4Q1O7eoXrdeNM4pGyHez7Xaoo5aTm1t6Pe1Pe3XtFrbbPxunH4kWvcaRzuojKc6tfU29r@YWPr3evavnr7bv/t3kFdoWHOduNg63Wt8aa@XaD6qU5Vf1/fPVQHr2qvX080dO/Dbn1fsZGA1crNOmFZ26QlLGridm439utbh2hQ@rRFxCMEX/vq4G19q4GH@l/r1Jza/kdfAz2o/8s7ykSJarv2pvaSGue4t1CF@mXr3X4dbpNAiYN3mweHjcN3h3X1cm9vm2l9UN9/39iqH6wr5/XeARPs3UHdV4jsyVUTDKIWpdPz5ruDBtOtsXtIc8a7t7B38KiTPxBhCMsaFd1mAsMMAq0lIu3tfwRU0IE7wFcfXtXp@z5oytSqgQqwqNg6tLNRhUTEQ7uZarf@8nXjZX13q47kPYD50Dioe9RhjQNkaMAg4yOxDlX6jluNfiK85JGY1TGc63N3qsaOqm2/bwBznZs44KChuYXJtvVK07wAj8DWJkrUx55BcG5vrHSmP12G8IE5vSMze48m8Zi0tbddpxlZO7nKpQnvaNZ5OuFKyU6jmSZJpNeMy5p2eHJx2ox6nT7umCbFZOPjPD71EUbKQ0idT86cKG56f4ULLC42m@9rTVroHjSbnn@Xkhk0biuht8Hn5fJ0GxELAitvbPxUKkL35xlCbfygDzrZUA8HEMgp1P9BTN@C89BTxWI71MVweR@AzdZRLMcmZzhKIdHIlx0RCyitkncm@D3S7MAFXQO@0GpinxSWkZypH9Of3tf0RSYH6wNJZ9nuKhaxiGU0ot9DU41Uwi4R@I/2SBB1uMpCHIafT92SXR3W/IXTfr/tep4pw3lHtA48db1bip@EpxPF85PlGVk@dtZhFGKz7mYVJjl/1iRTul8KQ26Ziz/NEf94Bhvx@YBdU66KN6v1pqX7gxSHRZKvtGsLXK/gTobO96b218YHrOZKq4/WJ76/Sr7L2IK9ILzl0oR3xOWO@efVsWSgAca@OIgkkfaQUSxaZYy9SZL5ijKeIdNV1IblD83VZyHP60QSUmQvgq5dJ2bjYXRtY09y@OV@7c3mu50dEp3A9tHTx0/W1p3E7dZfffn9iHrYoS17HRvQPE56GidZo2SLFB8eKZY/8ZT9mYGLRWSEG3nTafwRfh4Su42sJRMEGZobIzBWDyZ6uRB0yCl2wHHPMfw6c2RqBnAzTfXQmvPgmlX8gHQl5gFtzNIdc69d4w9gJ8PfDPGkQZqBNIuxi1/iXFpdsNzL7RhTUV7csOMeZCnkDB@LG7eEBrzVxfazuF3Lb5q3rV6MxZQR45W7nUsSEvcmsVDGrqInI/st@xnRG8DsPYy@/FXzGz1@1A7u2N1dEI9qowMi405SEvvU6Wa0bvSRhnyMsB5wqmZqeq6wy@9ppHjs6e3kxDGINRoYFQSpgY1vFvB64kdkskq2gH2x7Kkvwqlw3gE465pj9Ttx7qzmaCjrxn@IfjdeKZTASpycCNWukjock@Vj4sfCkDNDpj9FD4b/T6TJDPjPacVJ0FNqWU4A70RJhiq0ouUrEyW6MgcN1ulGSk3708cUzDe7Y86ShunTm2u5X0Mk0L0zNh8@stvDjjuDAGBybGzY4zcxSTsLaOn0Iufp4jgn6bXOB67Sc4WZKqbg5teOfVa7fHO2ghdPebLXZFX4moqqF7JwO@FRT0umiaW8uh/nBJxn/H8UH/AGSDLgmUvPxGp1krNKepQZOaBdLVkTTjvxmERq6bcbT@0eKMtFZkb265MvQygCvQF8ptvJ8U36Ssxzsx4XeSZWh@wFD27LsUzG5KNd1p2wIWY3BJz7bd4MQQiU0RUmiK5AZ1d9KTTl3mdDEVSSWh2mfgYhbr0CkZan1asEe96ZBIcm2L/ricf8UHa1TI6COPjQGNrX5QvqTTAmlLt3a7awWPHBQd@H7SIqk20JXR7hXlr9/pBUxwDtJhz9aOwV1Ae96RD24ouh9l9I81k01DsSRumnaqA2yeqdpxlxVc@oxdEItxXaBeYPbtJ5CAtRcU9ynV9TLjGv4dENs@kYXa@Ulfs8TXlONGG3pEzE52pNff0quYSg2mVoyBSM4mRxwTabXA/OHZLhd9UffsbcDxWo1w7biWdSCyTvBUonNXrs47E1kqYP@jHvaFBXYAckoURZNtISQ1Wao59odtJ2TbnUOyZ8l3JLvr@ehEmNtRRVlDKurp2Yby1PnQkqrWrXoImz0PLqY0Zl1oLr242LMfYWmj22VrlPvUSkVESJqN43qiOeRG4mTx/xpDf5q/djjB76gjNurYICYeisOFedlnOMH2wKPkThsG3viZIm0w4G2H7jpU@/x7xotg61279WMIrDMa0AWsXousgwmu5f@me95la/G5xG/SigdRr8zF@LxMPjmB/RYafD/lXMkYwkRqWVqT1On8W/jLhhw3tyLrluueaKR@HAtc0URsNx7UzcRPDOOYwA02i1zN@DSR9pSZlHj9NCTvb@Kdvjlb31G8s@LM8qLCf6AKAF3MaEBYXcIR3xxSTr8un6VIaTeRksHE9UXgXeDRZ7GYyfEYn4GCaDsUFmyizBbgRWZjdifNS@9tvsg3AIR0vhdojAO7HLn/0AEcNJivwIS4GKKj8tWUXlFOUafgjxML6Z3KtP/snYEwJ/Av3yw1ncMosRWMR1jLelWNYr2sso4cLmgRHLaJbEJMWi06hnXT/kKBfXk1CzyeObqMGWP6QUaTd7U1yJEenSwgcB99wmiZzm2MOksqyWPfbbARWkNnJLNzNseJv9LA9@HOLKzhkE05aG7FpI30SqFlEJgZMnzGttlMWn8u0jZnX1rr02QcDqLJMzKza4mzOaC99AiWR@xbFWf0jCODdBPW3qsRyP@oPlO1LvRtkx0zPbLFq3PO9WQ2BhtipNlg/aTNrqGI/jdWcSnwmmyVKMLc2Ih7B85eeEzSeJeF1tYrxVm@Nb6HATzVK7qWRSSfq7LWMfk@IlLHrNRJMMKcYdTkrXk@9HTWp482YJomHK8qrJEqMJkdEcy6MFaoJMCZXuTiHmPo37BD3aRDnU2yba2f1zI1EnjeSMy1OTlHFyCXrCcTsubZJcGnRgfAE3caLhJkIqUTiv/TEf5ZXzJ3AyjAQBCK04zKf7ULKDm3bWBB9xdICO24S1UBmSiJ42bAuHxOl/QjD2yq83d7TFQ3OcLx@vC6TrBBKtKjjXPEjmvjm9HjWvGcoUKWiIzyBF0qIp2XR291b92bZQPoIgpTlZW/qWfDTGUyuEDf2xk5rX0IHTqnTJzIjKDoQmiwYaC7RKOe2GslyF9hcNheNh3aCHES0g5LOLnxVdAu6810oJtVHkuj1GFk@TW0abp/IbUiRlKHkH@fVQFFWXF64EIBSMqXy1TBDg1pSxx6EAu96xOS@DqO4jKlgtY1jSR/aKmtp5zkgHUXWGR4@tHKVZOZ7ZMPIzgZBiMTtPigjpLLOzpFBoopuJi5Xjyez2pDlIITa8LxSnrtC9kqVh0nNCQA56XfJSiXJUVn5JczAnPnrsZRIT/ubUZyUrtTSZSvRJMDzKlydTn5YyqZlqV1ezRTMliR6eXWsmkUjh2QgnUuHP/cdXU2yX54lNqLXIyGgZ2j4bQclplUnrtsKvsXrOl7KNjmHg2TfDzfKrKSFWMk7Z5ztgV8t8ZADf7X@6tcYy1WCiYwWwXzpz2cWVBSFrrDlM9WgWVrrG017ioMCsafsd9f5wZyfj9vVkbAyNzsPh41KpBCY@sZ3fG9tqbCVF/WI2d7Fz0e0WB1d/Gb4/KbLsD0MOCVAxK@iQuoQGRVzoD08lMgRwoKzIndcXWbHWv@h07BAMOKFE51G3SU7tDUHxBBQlRi/vD3kDiEHqCfYXNBDt@0Ulo@8qEEVTQzHHUFQaJsGXOXN6RuTBhw7ss5OTKgYGwWysmWje8qobXzCDILIJdxa7L/a@pObJuVdht9v31QfEQoangIVvkwV2duwCJcmCE0a@3XsRsz9aX4WXUde6V4wsNq8DnJmYTJwJ4xcevvH3w9P69cDNHf2co2mFmryCZq7AP7Wvcqc5TzuLvwNY4UNC@065z4OB22I6TWamqV6P4PSJMHpY9meufTJZPN4T0zS7PTeIOhvdAjtroKZ7rAsYX/bcvdySG7InxM19ui53QMOSwNA4wefK3Urgqtk/Tyxejjqdu0lFDgMgHftdElEiofw5gchnADwC9fAjesKL9k95GtY7Ew5FRMFBsI5puYMCTRRwnPut6m9Xbq1WU0uDlRVVq23SQz6vaps1tY0Pm5tqm9438f5DdfXx43WRudveF/q4aT5@U5sEg3c4V1pnw216pbQq7o3BWhtdvFSsLvnrS83q8431uHhU28S1fnr69//63//9v/2PYk2//C@8bPLL0c9JpkKhUFxqfVn64ds63o@2j5eXTo6WBsfLp@vgsr@z1/B@Y5QPUvPRwvDEWZRZwPrKdqRmnc3eZ3RRZWL5nQfDzyRdKmqxFRcX9ddYIkexjF1shdb3EPcoT2gJb4IOTC7lCYlFAjrGdjz1TiuEAR7NN0RJwgV2oFJezlbMxj3cwSQZklOVRe2Jh3XWyxB3WlJPCriLSzNWPurFYQ874Jes80rzHCeg32jU1Pxb/PlNfLrZv1YPPrnqQUk98NWDXI5/ymvP6Ku3VIxwO1ey0XIgl/MpJT1agJmhiiNW9Hj9wLF2JsjtOEscsgeQjJsKziy34Pxk9ceXZSTgWnzqLCDWp5ItEj5kQpHFL0u9b9QtXyjHt1zmqg0rCk29iuHKrBOVpH@hAgWxGAKkNZ8LQSp9qhInfXwjGU9F80X3tcPRhBgwyLr/cofHPT7QXLTU0zbPmbUUwhyx@bx8xdy4LpehGW2kSP0pAnygIsvJEt8kXF5cdsTK22olN1NuYdvt08wntg7jcGRs06XQ35TFBGLNbRNuqafvtWhDbjleUbkoOV6xqspN2n4rxypyftEdRQN9XYFrx4D6ktT2TUYSepQBCRzx2V@ZHmG8UWA8RU10iwTLGqt2H02XkdDTV9Opg72CnBxZRCj@7NLY/joxtr0i3xIx7CA8wEglpnydIOrG2uvKkIl9GgxPEB0w6HBAtZGcm/F@HmK2TmDc7yRIFxgym5yn45masjgYBqfnga8Wd/uHw2DcoGmLNJ9Rq@BRC@GCCUhg8OmqZzXPICwt0l3CFEmawpZDCF7QHevwaNK3ueTOCbrUDAXtdgWDIMNOTMnwa6avJuiYcvV3dIKN8pTwTk4jtYhlyQtLIw0pZ1@b4WE2NXQcU4M9dpKBk3ME1WRkGl7QhS4w0Z7zwS9J8i58BOi6c/oWoL6KsPYM9WN2Og17QWZyGnQdc9G/uK5kXsR45lCUYo3kaChPymnEO2BFeuTPWS8QMjcZd0bOgusufIp1OLdFex5hJ9@JLX4xUFESgI4DmPHNEPWuF4mwnJih0hgYBdVgy3@C0OkGp4Tf@CoYgxU/Lbo/3it6Rz9/6h0/cD/1vn763WNMtEg2s2xeLerDbCOx9FihmbHoZ16NVVpsXA1@6mUzfOopucNikYAQKbpHPxePvxYJoU@Lnveg@GlRCJLpMmBSnF9fEeCLU2guZrEoLjoL3gPPdL77Y9lTNLfyL/pQPnjyS1iYRSVv09M6Z9ghUHxP97cLuXISF5@ulh6tlh/RSug0vM4PwwvMt/n44iS8JlUixnKWpp5Pv2e4IUOIb9dxsE4fr6mdEtZE7p7E@pKSFqF6mHM9TsJWVKYgPEH5icrsLhVXXLwkT4DDRyz4fUUsZ/KyLygxHbS4z8X8GffPUU8QQ65N3g4RjoSVgdiI8BZqHpBN8JWbONQzw2WZ7zkV1BZ8tzIQ6t7iojVb9Pq9vFbWvMLyOpRo3JrpPi09LU2O0akhmhmhS1qZWr6nyhs/Pvm3/7n32@JocWO1@GFIv6PF3xbXni7KIz3Q20Pzdrm4sfgc2da@LY6LtAamxyf/9r@p/MZfCA5Sxs/pz8ZjA2ttvLiRr3KRr4sba/RQXl2lev/Pv/4rtWFJVmyIxbrU9BUjtm4oshX0mHcpXTXQSlmWLqdihS9mAYZYGNLanF5gGHW9@rTE23SL2qriMtSer4w9ip7i2TBrxKZCspNh7ClIM5ICVVSQF5DGhKKjLNsNY7YB5k3RVL/cL6zFtAL4RZtzJFUmphv3Y5gMLcmyiDrQlRppPS8PG6Ufc4l5RyVnbErWjQqJpZ2WtU8frhM7vO2Ho6iVtZIww/W8FVyFJwXwYSFsX9Caqhd3@78Oi5fEkufl1afFDjb3i2zHXRwwpPxgXPidFEEdDIgWhmx06qsh9UD/HC68fI4WRAr9TnImZeJJkpY9CFuyh5WNSUxZ5I6fL8fDaE4hVaVd/ksKPCJn6kCQVqy0Tz0qubdfUbmVJKPk4zWvB2zesnGsdoGRF2vYAcumgsNtwO6gaU@hNjzlS0hcCl7XJUshaLebgU5znYWcCZXmOwtnYXdQzXXEvTt8p@LERNNf1MwboeQj7CDk8yzoAOs8HAW0RK/m@AvW42kNcJOiz1oTV3EpWTs6r17Vt6scdWVO1VdS9RX1KLSEtJ6EZyxvbMrOJrKliq3KYdjEkdrMiqm22ARtHhb4BxjE0i2NDq4l6ObwDUiiWtocbVVmd5vPa2HikatQ7uzJ1qJErnYW08uPvskhN6ihO6HeglRGAgJecCuwUKb3A7kBUTVhRqOeI/78JpKNfw8NhtuwB1eitts6cT4q01LvErFvohHfpVREAu1X1rbBdmT2SEAnLraSELQ5bLzkPLBUp8KLLc5ouqPCYaCNS6hcTvapjloqCS/b0dFrJVAEfciVyqsPHz1ee/L0GaKcLejWzgaDQgWsAgZnAcFgjdqlRTa@V6u55Zx8Qgjq6SoBfRZYHMDBrOvK84zb5yvvXrVc0sBKOYZ1xWE0pLjermSQKcRhWMCMQGsUd5hz3R8rR2jY8ae295X@EX8b/4DMcMYdbSCkt/rhbeqZyjkXhwNVFszsFMd9CA8qnk6x84b9zj68TYSwdRW2p4pewwPE6GzYvzg9s7mjoF1bHdKAIYKzX2qsoF6Go9TBmIUVdFG94dCwbl9UDbyj6RbAKBdTAnQ@AU7DTPutDLSlKUbHMk1C8KyJG6s4QrRMR212Zu7s9VV9d3sSsUU7DB3DLdiWraTcsSczOJBBrF6ruYdEXe3tgq@SapnkZ7wqs4ArIV@Zr8MHuCvdQiBqiypGVrPeMHLnkaXMvJi6Nk2LUj8Crxkwy6XbSWnutZpWgCBGEOrdpESI@cl5jk2yFCe7kzFOwcu5imUj@iaKY3YwpyvLedqilDNxVIEF5waA2Lcp5aQhpQp6lB/rHHhZehvBHOVWNLYGtBlyslINZ@bkMBNsdRuLA2xEHTe0QPsbu1u@2q7Tn50P2z4U5c3aT2h3EuL5ZnzLGt9yRTV2TBfY3mLZ5hY2U7/hihIxS0k7jE0RhPDtSFTEMPUaUG/saNrLoD7KjO3jlCvAroFWws3uqB4kcPTCeyALevGeuOLg6zr8rSKbV9OSJnGpooeFbHHNH9gWTRbSWhNIQso7gFidBJE4akm5fSFleLFAZ8070GsXw9iNndk8nWFZWVCR2r5TJLJnefZGysxji1XNFqsV9OM8vmC@ncsbJ2Gnr@@iJcxxC2/c@2O8kb87c@T/v2CO@j@HOx5q7nhYgewR7kjchvONTg7D3p/BMSdjnoOb7eg0wv5Qx3pFI0q@BYAFHjDEHVJKLJfQthvEiXJnJ6xMzkcwElp9jIsBf6jxj3TjH1Ugc/lxO/x/tfH5f3DjH@vGP65grpnR81q1s9yt/2NanKqEbvbDzO6FuivZvD/a0jXd0rUKZtMZ3fyf3tL8f1BLn@iWPqnAY4IcOIj7@vncLJpI7WCr0UjNLQqOdtrlIo79bK70sPZqV3O0eOh0L@KzKrR19Yfxf6rxfwppxE8IQ4eziMQ2NFnLy/JULsuLZsm7HAqXrKQl0l7jGd1qr56w0vWInqBESPPG1lAvVEgh9yUxPW0qpPpjKn2TyeeuOIts18EycXBuLaBlRVj20iEumq8Okrm6lswr2@wDWW0d7r9e@S9ChvPgs76FRsija6/CbtfMJPYS7DDxOqUbYzUHsA/0miPDKpqcjOxI3/ZO2GXhZqnGji0m5sXZiwQ5asP5H62lzqFvWFG5sWVEtCno8mZVBdNcs7yQL9R2yTS7ybrFf4hLn2kufVZR@3phcBOpAr3hp3kxXaetPn48bw6QUgX8YACWfMo/Z1T9Xw)

Run: `node plumber-node.js polyglot`.
Note: takes 3.5 min to execute.

Code:

```
line 1:...............................................................................................................[]
line 206:
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
```

Packet `0` is dropped from line 1. On line 206 it is pushed to column 1. `]`  is increment,  `]` – decrement. `x` is for SILOS.
Empty lines are for Retina. [`[[`](https://github.com/Radvylf/plumber#branch-droppers) duplicates the packet, one copy is pushed
right into `[=` and printed, another copy is dropped. The packet doesn't need to be duplicated after the last digit is printed,
so `][` is used at the end. Spaces in `] ] ...` are for CMake.

Answer (score 2):

## 409. [Kamby](https://github.com/henriquegogo/kamby), 17232 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"F :n^*giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1_e#8g= ma cep:s561?<p>3s :
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({1ec07768-8988-4285-ac81-73225e782555}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKr4xJtvipRUKumWbtdDLaluXV@SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElsaK7Z7fXbXtmPT1tR7vt8W33rGfb64kY78TMuL1jz0TY@3HCMZ/8A8qPjQ3Hhvsf9J6TCYCgREp12/aGY0ECyOfJzJOZJ8/Jx0Fb9wY//WkML3LkWLO@5YzJ2PDGpOua54YrkgczsqObXk7VOA5D7br9ydCwx16ZixGFEEu3@xO9b5CeaY0NN0M8wyBtw3IuwF8lZGtiTzyjWwObRohtXJBDu2N2AQIZO2eGbb41XPDLEvLQsK6GV2PScYZD3e56ZOSa9pj65gg50sHSm3TOiN72xq7eGZuODV55Qp7blj5sd3VCg49cg0UqEADVOaNxln2KhDxxXM@AFJyO4XkOOpbAUXdN5/Hu04@vhVdk8rEOmRpZxvRa8opCXpiG270eQyWfnh4cXHfVyFcFxyYHN7OkZMnuZOwcjq/Dz5HdvmHrRBVLonrdMw/IHBtWUS7K170KUJ/G2OwspQMeB6YLtav7tUg6ug21hXWZIsZwNJ4RgdW/bllh3XpE98jEm@gWDWdPhm3DDQJ6Y90dm3afXJjjARkPTC@MR0N7I71jCF3DMofm2OgSy4RITs@HAqDtLjkzZheOC1Xuw3RsawYRjY7ZMzFKkA8AiFdiPDAYnKE@g0q2x9A4iE48yIZlBNCSXAzCPzTakz5xJuPRZEwgb13T09sWAG3PSNfo6RNrnCFt8AMkU/eLgWH7jRnAiQDi1GG5ej2hWTMWbV7vdokM7RjycWYQE7BGs1UmmgbuxHEBaxAqyJEPjLZrVkZjCnUGVdRzyiQny@C/H7pgbnXLc/zMLGcNPW3oq7TOEO6R6/RdfQjY6BoUp58eHhGv47hggxvDsv50G5iOPiZbWyS@//RhnNTCahHdNhdWUZVcQhXEAk9yrlsTaCHRmnCgftwwNodVFt@Il0kc0KLKJJslWei2RaLmAEmKXAID9H9VU@DOE7VIsgr0oBzR1EI8g2n1XL1vWgaD1EdIBWz8EESFp5wlmlJkIfuO1WPBOjTBAtGKJF8ghRwpwLNESiqkiOCzRCnl4M7DDdBKkB0Fbg0yJ6sM2KL9Q3vFNrdHevrQtGZ@CjSJDskppABQId8KQFeLAAXemoa3BjfN2vIVhT0eANYH@jmAFyzzDKmSERImrEoJXlIqJVHKiKSXJe8NMHlAISAvVyQFSD4P2MhCFgDDahGSz8msIN7AsCw/2sDDaDS3BRluyHkBcFGEWpABnzIitAA32IHuqUDgVKBmKhAoFYiKqoJZwyQgXB788lCl@SxLZqB7Z5AQS0ft0goAyg5gFMQ4EjMFkQQQoMYIoBqqOwsNQsMGkdMI5B/yUsgToGdFhRSzpFgggM@STKB@FMgXthYF6KgC@VEQGLQBBRqBAnlSANsKAFW0HOEiyFY09Ie4GsQF1ChZiJMFM1Sckscb4kHrUCBJBdJU1dKiMULe1ByUN6fRVqrmoXYL4Ad4UyGvKjQpFXKrFsEf4xYBh0VsxNB0GSJ0xAPUCjZ7aIuAjBzkh8KFsGBWCxrDn26NBnobqTaL2e5h1Dx2hzyiEaLKWDx4ZxGbkBUZwGBPgOyr0AI02mvgnQ2TtxQAUkfwRtekhNoygYYpIYYKGdogX@uj8QJtSp7maDQbD0I3lbk5QEBNIIJGX@/MQk/ogZnQc@Ga19BVpTR3AUjOoqsHFNaZeNYCSGjIqjQp49y0Fm5F6tY19G7P9AbvFnnN0kTahj62zbNFKrlcJoJUPeKRR48lp4IWDTs2BRi2@gM0LcqiFjDMyAkraCnLikKz1zZ6E7tvCKViJH/UZzxxxzDALNIsMWfX7PdhbF7AUTK0mHTAXDjnaA4tTRtzoSNiF9N0TRjG75POABiL0LPE4JdKCxiaijBmehtHdwG4MRgNSjh@9cwpad/v0NFjkUGN4qkzMEdB4PLawJHKpYlMi/lI26CYe1uUQ/KMV1N87Zh2Ik7iSW7OwZjDOMzoiA0D2wscrXD8xaYL46tDuYcF@UzYwQiZBKQtD/Yw@lpARqFSOjqOxDguGXRcDeCYY5FAIsAOGs45sq90cFxKxqMDaNtFbhW4na7hugTDAovrZehQ603anvFmgvzUIl89GLsNGOJ7ummFGaDjiD6mjAC84x6kN1vOds91hnSwGeJQajnOaA3bAgP3BQJ65FwYi6wvxnV9NLKAewJ3gzFvkJkLnfLdlEmPpsoyBJEwHlQ4AKRJAddhukaH4t4vOsTWgD9ZzmKZqLX7GkJ5EGGrNOgswHJ4GMeeWFYZ@B2jQ7Sa1DXOJXRhrNcyy4V5CJgxYKl8EG0deGbMOc1FCOm@KlI27zSoWc8ZLheNja@HYdEHJjJI1oU@g9rrwdBqTPUhcPYE2WfouWQILYbVINYEyC5YrEPSdez4OIRy4QIzC4UOS0IZZsTJ2BwaIAU5EAVrPEszjaM7zVl7Bk2ZYisrUrGH5eQaokTuOqKYQzbiwDoLsH3dSQexhmmbNm1BwCp5yOu7QCqZGzd2SaOhw@0CXzfyJT0RDRjwBLMWERQ81tt9DrxDISKvatgeiBeeSEyUw6Dl950eNLYLE8oOBAuiLmB3KBIQBaHTVOyIHEU5NqDhmUVM0hmNCLjDoATN80AuAivqvDbJW/C0BiBKdCauOyPTEdSEOYRQ447T60HrfWuMBgCCDLukM@tA94RKxtbDdR1KYDqj5WIubJsGhLFRONk7@nnSNwDtwLj2UErFJr8owGhEi0BRoduMqbV1wBQWoTOaUbRwsUWMnuOI6N51DI82Fsc9C7s@JuYZfdo1oJ/1FsRoiEw6tFKbChddoDx@90L4mCC3sjCYlN8KPjZs6DodaJXQ6aH6sE53SQ@E7QgLi/KG3ukYo7HfThxKzkw7wvc/O0C@n7oKPjDRG3CbO2TrWquBoGHLifCyKAdh1ke@OKIjrfUleoEyHqHoySiLNbuRPIQ4v5Y6/wrDLOXgFb8mDyPaJVAIokRiMkZSgtTR7AyQFo6R2lB@G3qbO7lZfHCLJu8OidAL08bcKEB2OFEKnTAf62EIcFs3AYkjC2HVlhww6JLDHaB1b7gCshNm0upGXUVJF4Eo3gV06NjOCqiAzBAuBln2oXVBG@MJUg3dChsj7S7eUh0hwV5MMuFABmPoaOS40DMY0ZnRGQVaZZHW5QviiXCsSIrkwfLQCkNGHAf8MY6CEGFk6dAWsIthTwXJSgdKAUSMCcpA8xyWYiTDtNdTWH7@LijpZ40JxlLbNlA4090ZAwLFg@EZEpoR03WBDJ7jIMHGoGAwEWk7hTFB73aRsiI6aL@/nriILXpv0jan16XxDjqKrz3uXHdJDwVxF5gO6ESJeM@LJyvUncaMePGSMxpLNCp78hCQBhKhyhM9kO1hkDgAQnMyszsJfqmL8RnCT8a9Ip8EA0ZkPBr5BESF67lD8QEbzfAM@jW1VUgfhm9BgKeAbjQn6CGJ6KG7wGdAJwQps1TqtnVyBdTDJcJ0j4kigUiiiNkwLcPuhmn5iMC8RMsrsiQ8t0MNQmRUwxJgcFpyOkgsIfADMUEj8uAgSf7Yig6U22N@lK9hjhObzseRBGNFkuQyZH5hAEjQzJjAfJgdc9zy2ZX79wPGZaNahcYG3BSQzW4yKtEGE5ciUGoILFJuxE9EHDsnY@wbiSSUFwPPWW6AbYKWWq2Ry/HAhR5H7XMOAgFaORtbcoBYv56fmmeT7vWKttERA/HY64BpMjtjvsLB4M96Q/U2rMaXsApSbxyxio0X41PQNxovdcUK5f1gruEh@1v1sxKp4QTmwG@rK1HEovpuiwa9N@tYPkvATNDZGTVqQ/bP/AmtkBBlfJ4g6LQ3eioDgt2BwSFHu6ePqn5fZJ5S27TLSw6W09Et6ryJwfkg7uPDB8e7xz/fWgHDMtvl6w6SmS3mcaidTIW@PZGyolrejMJYAH7Yuh02RlwOw3O@NxGcaYRVmnVgcJkG6Hx2/NXrKAFOCNFBUwAz3tdYGhYGmC6urXuDa4Mw6afTkGQYJQhLhEMSwAwNmHX014P8HE3evsXKu56pke@OObMmOgMQOEqHdhBPRM9rDFjg1e6xEZHGBS7UtHHBYWGKhgzy8zFyzdczQ1npSJP5@NnB/nGVgvXn1QQaRPLGwEvpbleENm9NQARfFQbIH5g6JC0uMo78NM3rSgR3OksIXtQtWQMfAKCsIzpEsIZB0bwB5H3vetmoq9AJWwC1UwjX@cooP9T5shmN5AOHuA6KvKtGUeqxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx1cjmjkC1Fh63OIs1uFChdHIBxIOAbXfA68wR0ERdcpM9W@9k/eXwj4x5lIkEUEIKceRYRaVqexaH0Ipgk7kl7IKE5liG@oBSPJ3xSkuLB@oDY8ajwGQm/PzXHCTnJ3koSwkLqu7uH6sMgsD9lTWcyqNCAsjiOTG4P1/k6HrQR27GcvkNSEIdxh0GCwDatLeZu37Fv1JCOjljUGC4VAv3FiRt9BGON@ZYKjjRWVFxli4667V0AlVbyGiKJYoiCkmh48bV@rgO6FuU@Ofx8HwYRJSfLoVmmF6AgEoeiC02diCt1IAIkJPr5WVnAcNnwRm8PPITIuh0W2id0YcTdhfdKR0oxRWll@JVZ@sS5gfHXzuxa0wIX1rTAEEHZ4dOjx4dP95/sftYYq7nckj0rl/KAOEivDbyQOGB4w96aYl0Ti4XgYtA3XOxeQAUmIKAEq0YTzwXCLWIQkWVgTathC66JT5yBHfeS1wtzgb7Ca7vDmtAT7HwsqB8RBO2uhcKIy1atcTzH9jMYj0deWZKglw8mbRGEVul1x7H0vkTjwcBgWZKCosvhM5zX8FbFgMx4M4PFYJNbwDrM6Ayibg0dEF7o2jeSBpJg4OmslWX2ByAL4wK54SbFsAXT0khdkBBAVpbCslECTG2AW/8d1BPPmvZHilpk7VqR1azEB8GWuj@E3egZIDolYLQCVCSvWUnjfuM@mQGVRkjXgcSImKKTHB7BscAiwEjSWVOU8wPkUGqB86VIKyiO3kxwNheolJSTswUln5NALAMxDXhWAefchKE@7gyEsSMAPMHp0XmDSCvseR3d7okp3xBkFvi@e1BUrf6y0bCbwKA37tO84fpzfdasK81khdyMkvLDJyvQepeKh203cIC2S43QNOmbrKFnXf0mOevqtHd1iTQejvwxRxiRJ7vASL11gF53jWjfwwhS1FNKLYWVMPA7acWEkIVROXwgpiToUDDSQtOTMF8CML3IHkLLAboViUAWsxkhwzQbD4B@aCSxR03JmxwuOms@1VjOCk4Ki6MZkDwaCIm2oGGGAg@a4IhBwKzEQQRCjgf94ywLbKtJhJSh3I9dz3TiHl2mQdYKJ2y9EdQjne/u4EDh4RTlGAbosPPhQAHtC8cJcmHEcSpf99iEKUTytxsE8UFcDCHQhYFwUtwON1hAO6Sx6AwBEC9o2jhzO1hMdOK8AzR2SJDmCec/gImx6QJGHwoJkVlBdllBWErUZblIZ7ZzYSO0tkGKQtscs/UGZ@LisrvZjZYNgmsqCwPQaOEiQwtdn28bHTbRyyLTUoAcqpOhMXRwNgMYPEqNDFoEna3tozjq4aQ59GxZwEVLgC@QnT0gpB2DTVkJQ5TjoFXvk/jYlXaFzyVdeAsd6hb2DgsfqWK/0k8DBCzvtKATNf4kLGWQnCEN9IJO@aDng4Dj9psWtixerzojw74udjKhNJGs0B0R8Thbh7qMb2xsxMvxWjwDpm0wbaFpG01pMG1Tk0BNGE5EE42RoSb0rdMY6NaMz@sB5GmyiW1giszLW3OU0OvlstbM6HXFf6v4TkJVAOYhtIAvgBNPVqtoTCb52gUuG4EIESn7Hradk45rjnwUfAI8CbNHuxfvdy/XqKB4fDtGhlUX5FYDudyEG2/U5UazcdnophvzeAZjJyt6FURUoJ/jxFDsu85kBLxjPVsWgLwm61q5WWlX43I8lUgUBQsS0pPJe8VkWme4TsQNaFOJRiMOKPWxU@8MXApvmlGTyRBRkI@eCYKOZSXi4mUR0m8nm8l0HOIm4xkYGarxOOCFrnl6tNA4KcEa0YE5BVRCx4RRNrqsQWk0XR/D7vq5MRrM3GiAcOIPGH2cxF9sm8HdRTiQRAn1WxY/ylMuTTYErDcLB/w1zh8iyzaasQGGYzltSEubtIKh/1zoDZ2xLn0qgtwmRkbs@EZcEgQYjKkPg0SL/cT0sAvrtuFMvOhk58o5WEwdXE8HEyCWwU65DLQqc8QZnYFD4ps7AJ2ES05I@HH1TGBrcAGAbkeEG4koMka4XgMMDt3bZAJdpLvC6MSQQjPBSE@wPJDLj96IYWoVGofImJDZtx3XEAAlEIOjG7no9kCuFiyNH9LJtxvDj@9LR1UcykwDKOKB5egUt4xcR5akRsNIfLuPUY6NLmcB/egBeRRZXbhGV0pxdKHYcQcwQkBpkBKrYW0NfQ/J8UZdcTyFqFwCx/yoJxMwge@9IF1VVfOdXK8c@GGrAGQPoJJQMLZByg68BAU8k34l77OZqWCa4Omzh/ts@oaO9zjC41Rea@h0J8Da@qLbsWH3M2Qf2pNpO0MT0BDEf3tmHTvOmE00gGXd5BCT283hxNLptNP1maFb43WctmPR2ajboi7CT1xPt3Q2Dxb47n76BMSN56cnVbEcCSTp58Nb08ap0NXJMnweRpc96ZJvsELlsYbJb@Z4HLeCDahIZnyPPHpM/O2nUEeBewHdgy6Fyzi@exHdh7j1FNh1fyKDWkNHP2CJBsTtqLj3zne8VOQ5uq8VA8NwCg3HeNdFbi8Vlbqfj3u9JWeNOp8JSJqshXOWOrNtqUtiajRLORYI96guhYkCytMw4VbVteEKNBzbYCOGi5tPwn0QA8MKVjePgWPBFTwY9C3kq0BuQimBbSc1gMkf4UINJd24/Ec6wAd7N7hY6GwjgYXmYhu0A8HgJiFLw21KxJ9@r9AuZDv@sqnHyKrjZtjMzlaNLbSjWOcyiVJiCwObLQCxVasEe/7WBcOU4vEwGIVK8wYxaDHp3oIbRQ13inh0vp@jUSqcJ4FEM1VloTEt7Dev4pJH0dAjfKMxvSern4FohBs3N@9LfaNCt1mtwVcl8In7PGx7RgTg@DAUmzvvDIDOkPR0GZVQPxO751hdgS3UQYMhTMTDCvL3SYQbSv19w4bpBntJ6WZeFhXpa2Qb6g2416q0djNAZONqCAi6zyW5OsucX5E6DHnnojeyzHGTzMWx0xr4m7Xs61tcGQ/quvrM4/xtNlWye/zxp3W5ySBwQx0X34qsFqfBTmlgnIFRwi3tYMLNQmNzTDkBuhnCxPIqImRqStdpIPsAgyVQIWFCfokw61fG1aIsPQOE5YSBOfdmwwwxknOxZ@njsWGzNsdWQNejmy1V@clUafLb/rpHmch0cQg4UxP9IIsVcnL6cP/4WISW6yXi@7iIVIbuqHcGwKCsK3SAyWjhy@ReN07uYZwkzhxw0NVA@mj58aFRV6DRg/wBqSPt6BtuAhyTuP7TAWe65EYjMg7NRxBu@eqMKY5CYAkjCWWiwMor8//cZqKWn88ytPg0xSSgO3G/DLg1k@LENt@IHgw0lG@FIL6wCuNFdTNBqdimkvT39A1x9RokLMo0QgnqdSK8BSoHgXnSbFbYNgQIiwKY20fs8jytCrqhvqoEVV8FZ2BpKAQ/evUdeVmXhVIzvbkKFN3f5u@FZ@WPwEUIy6A9Y2Wymwna3290ZJYHthzJKPdzKk5fOwhSJpvMwLNpbxo82LNFiQ7d4rW8VWt5Ixh0MiQldDYICxKQhJh/UsFvs9SfUn6QeTAadUgkyWWIdBVRTq6uKA7JpkooDsGkEFYZ80D6BML02IHSPPZPKUS5A9pb/b0s2GcbHB@IWcuLxejDWHjp/Bp3Kpzz0XiMOzTtM4cuOYWmliwqOeQIw9jDM@tmTNwHSx9LQcM8sLDqutx5w3aPPlYEoCsv/po@daBz@j4vDEykLh3TF53eX5Hy8j6WpWT9HbJ0pAUzEd7cEVIoFWngXrttrgsKSMCtacF7RTAgUtieVTErKsGxB5yKgfEICBeTXhZFv74Fiizh3d/K67//29e7gP@btTOAgQInP0NDC4ZurCmht7ay/KhooY/VFcvm6CeWqVPEUNNdIDu6C0XSrdCwGjTdByAIMPwPcVXDr3Fom/gArvGWZsZyzhYlg/fqRFat69lAMjvrwl7bEsaSoitQINh1KRIYE2QaNBIlXawSjClbBYqI2EjG7s5UsG@L0MbM6n0wGU/YExjXOyvRHOF9W9/0Q8o5va0YEts8f0uVu/rZpOsIo7N@yKfmV4RdlJ4uQwvADvgr0i00ri4@KyDbjB681wVbDG3SBX3d1So8e@KNhDaVwrvMRjvC8JYUXIs91wUx/XOEoWE91kyLPj6wJfrQoaH4GzIk3O4qRJBmXkOzpbdnyIMMvnwrCzc3AMWpdtJpWVuzuj0arY@PkiSNXyqtjj0VOwwfq@YIJLalVmCzaLTA/ibbO2oVhitzqFuC2o0Y1xLzVXsjbgQNl1VpHDz/QQ@B3NrIcUDqTCzdXZhuaeKLfATLCOtmpP1h48jsOMAOjIhSEBU1GDoiAwYlmcHuvEVCuKOZPiI7MMxVaAxOtAihaTUJcDpj3LW6pk19AEFju0VxT26kkYjOOkx1nAu817IPAxBN2XP1iPZ2Za4@gDgJVsfSYRxfOxwsTQ7i5OMdDfXC9Az6WI3Ys5UZHXesle7LXSCY9otO493VrD3TcjxyQp@3IajvAhbYc3WDjuLS1G2BToZHzbfQoGCbxaJCdavvWPliX9LhsbbWJ24P6b7//lAKF1IoRbmDQgXsj2Mr/nstXT@T3LO7KoiemXRxi23EeMsQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2YFcpDFFiU31rUkYl1wu9Fnw/hmGjnWoDYaO0Yyy08DdYYRSEQxjl7HYP0tq2dtT634YUboBtnBXISKVe2YZMFjR540qJaqsfMkYiix/OInqWRNjYqwUNJ61Xxt4wv8WIePDMyX7xdj0Z@pxcQBPx4Sh3vqS4QflGsdptN1KTHTL7Bh3szLLRG0E3PcIRecjMByh4WaMvj0ZLdXqknRmH9@OssEo6NJOdyl36PNl6VDxDk5piT/3DHrfKjExCQ/3qFVzsiz7DExkxWXJcpskpYVxX5vsuZQwdVmkvAiLq2xuxLg6DYqW6C7ItSRIXSfY08ClkmSbtjGe4fMDqWnbcawvU1NAVPHMsgPSqkB3@95WYzfYHf8cC1lMXXg44dHurZu0YKONL1sCflBovq3So0tCH1SbAi56DnFBatl6@/RNZIHprlTwfC3OCbH9v9Z6XtKfDVHEoli4tdcxDtVpG5bOXtN89jZ4JVG7Fd4y0fAXa3Fxly3pLpbiY9eI0mgGyDK7IKUMjKFBrbdw@XoXtXX4r7WBpg7e67ynhtGRpvtGZ12AkQl0wcbn0hpyhFkaOzbIV2PcaohyioWbWX3XdRQ4WPVbieTDod43mPqY2yjlYsICd9MwsW5hXD11UWY7aDoQbaEXZH2TgE51Zsy84L0S4JNZB@p1Mrx7uu1a5@/gHOgH9PZ1u2hvDrH2wBnYA2PAtq6HtnWdA9rjmKn7uS3rkOv@AHfTjUZLu@yj@LQcy/oQfCJpZITScXor87SP52/x8NiXgssO@/uvOyfv9DGjHWhY22sGxgTGJc8ZOyNDoLZ1QS2c6GHPdTQ0WKT@WWeQbpXzASPB@2eFf6ds2ded8WhEX62RNfHog0YV6LHpu/imHtuaQvdlOm5ffOsM26LvKPr7VugS@GoS0zbHnQGeW2ct2@g77c7AvCvTvq4MKZjyYdYPkl0RMyYRHqKzaJmAXncmYnupRv1P8HW4rtL92SM2rIWGW/iVVTN09GS4MNLPOh6bDUUTKeOEcKQ3svPjZXoCv/xmYo4XQCN7mcLpXbYsgYZ1efd3T6zlrOgxjQUZ9ndVrG2llElHhlwwZGB4lHXJLu9zi3QxTWOPdRmKlpLmKLIv5cug29/7Q2cHzci8Lbgvta@lTUsrBzl7MOl7Nwkmm67vAouGj/XTFnQ7dWTKGsYs3fZf69CsWhKes4R3C3iuiXHrmkru1kUVGk6xBN0x4dWCF1TdZO0cmmWOPPYkQm/tUpy/lwlk8evrhQw3s9XCtF8xXaPHlkDQdBeLOHRc3IkMPIjQwZV0nEFHYs4YL0a4bKcPRF2wyCJwEHYd27Jym9Dq6g/HTOGzp0Zfx73Wj80xbtZc0Spok121vehO2F@b6J75tQmUbF1jQ6URbBnSjWoXQNsKeE/0vtl5tFQRYSZ9BPs7Pdlrqfmj0826uBiYHu5oCg23TExhk2ONGFtdC@SGFSGvz9uH@jIWHYidxFwZetXcujOa4YG1GTXdNq1ujuksq/9eJzqu2wR2ayYuJsPRxPNfq/NA90xFZ6GHZ9TduzABuPAGSCsZ6NZ49Ux1ZMoVuDB/UFwY13Hjn5uW0yefF2UCTBswYcicr2g4D2B4PsINOa69oiXStD9w2RMnOgSXFewN1K2B5ypsc3z7bM54jJtzgjcWho0ceEJBeoxPcefLQhBOV2Pk8d28/uJ09B3jO7S8E2fidgw0hipPomKBn6qxF@w@xhMdDqpsuYhKaR3Hgu4FBmtll@k49mQsuBP71lEhf@uoUEaFV5FmQBJf23/yPBltDXS39l1caKASbWFau2HgWiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLPGQqWo6pluF74izi/qkOpRcP3RWyTtHMxhAPlhgAuI/GT40OrhseGfaT50nju3AaDQCQjk8NpjagaWNHqsjYrTHeLAe8NO9M5kTCnbNIMS4DX1ktKF@rYXpQ8YiBvihPtbXDEV0bpDKf6HpzrZiWm3DfU0n/SLmdSLtcoYeGVMqW6xvMKwPCuNOh7HEOB@31EeWVmy8kePY7EmprQwv5cntVAWGAvr48IVyETfiL80LrJTPlov67JztEjG6TC/GurK6Rtux2POWPUm2yfYE6K5peNJjVLNA3fJZIgD35d1KQwq30pCFaASc7Lnu0UX61aLGAqQy/RJbgAa623FwJcw33LI7J6Ib4Q4yHe7tZxsH2oD4KVAsvTPx9ZXelS1r2B7Sx1qBIVKbx0YbTwW1qUKRsT69WZlsZsjXphDZ0RXqIAjIFXbqPEkcgTSSvHvYWpKjlrFqjuiDUuq1y@V0s45gm0bnrY6zZg7F12Jueskfyiw9pcY1c9WRbkRnkSWdHrZf2ZOWt64BQ2MZwnjggswvjW@b3g40vaxYD5kMDVxkXl6FWcu6Ot6AFtZZvZ4eElfXEHx1g0BLQtWDjD8Udtdyngge/s8efCLBINzKZwPtJ0C67l7Bh8xPXNt/fUgLPHK8cc@cPoN84ymAdeQEi5WDKPBiPQNNqXWFgNqzJxabfehH9l0Nu1QcE6hCaEGwKLkeG4JhnwtUF930ZokcduhL2kUFwmOjK/iqGHClQXgcnP8Kg/nvFQuoUdqImz0ViSF2ms/62z9XIfcioAzAbzljYeTRtzTyjg4fPzsVR56ycnzaHeDpiBt83JJuB7UoR6akXutuZL2TbUfrmt5YenCiCHuPD0UMsAbfbEVDgBeuzC291s57BopkJX2tFIS@xng1g/jo9Mnj9OKIJknsDVxnaCSj3nsnJxk8afLJyUrvaOwD6B09Z7o2@uG@oiRXNN/nNl0dXEc9V6S0DtKpAdIoNMZHTDXMncxVxxkZ3dPZyPgUBk@k4N4HJp9fW8in@rnZx15ISmsRRTsqKYn5bDKyMxuEbcMN3@vq88wcIbXs0JfEXmu3oyDnoEmutpp7uG3F/zoXQ2R/J8KXi6TIN1trVJWxpHt/14wpirIOzyd6D@qV5NZW1nKAVevDlnP@AUvJhi@8CKGTMIZWJZh37iMvCEMg3RI@cHredwRje@02mNsAhM75lR3@wrBnui3Qtazb2IsyxMZNbbcG@dz4gAWpcIfPOepLX7nGF26pJ4kONSbvSPjUjUTZ23tweFeEYx@Xt4f6@OlzcqR7qAfl9oDRHBsfkOMFZ/RawHkrVMK3djm16wIo9VZ4/dHq/lwmJ7rbdezZ9O5FOHoGFYd2qt84hIU2GsiwzKm5aqzqsHmto9XbjO5Kmx3icGZLfHBUP44P6P23/oWiyDLVfoRvRWbWO2om6OAkgSZ9hir1ol6nhyFp6CDfIoJDcqU0@tiY4nYUNhu8SqhfOb7lbxn7Csn1w8ltfsVb/LK3pHfDDx2JJsrKLQBzt/iRnBh6P3asi4Ej7umu4a3Yf7wyQ7cVpHRLQUoR6uwrbKcLi755PYuPRxf818rWemqM3exo4LTN7Moy7PZQzyV5gvrab/r72yl0l25v6Tv@kQ9mX53excRYmdAT/e1qD0ppzlZ6ARE0BhN6JOKm9/ICaRt4XsPum0zFI3ngjPep7RbBLDzxvHovgjl6OBmtzzHQRvwqxnVyvhTwBcjMzoVHHuDRuAWbvkL2x/1xq93X8bQknBhETaePTneD1vXsRFIjKS5y8dnRkjMeHh0/O4m4ucZ0uk7oFabrZMiVPotUn55ml5Ldqr08X4Gs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBjNh9cnKTJKD4NhgPrcDnE91ezJguVVjXGdOThis9j2ZTuo1yZU0P2C62VX5uZ4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe1GqhOqZWa12rPDU@o2sPwAaRMWNLGFBf8ZIxzQ6CHNIoazuqc7ZgfpayezIamPZ0pddwXRy6izTx2lvdDXbJieVckMehVqF15EFdDVw/N@x1xGnVYUWhpN3OhWnXWKp19cI@oOK/1lXJg3WM2jWagRsibqMmGP@4Ix0Elk/V5J3hPzkJgt8dds9ycP6@a06GdwemYNPpuwO6t5C/6wDNu4Ph90bOBo5r3x00aE7l8gPjAzOx8cEhh7OO8wF5aPd6dwfa95y7Az2ZWGMTZZbVQZ86Ews1CKzy23f7K91rW7VGQyyL6zxRobs3cJPr/XFfpDPxQAYyQ@IZRhRem@Mlx6DNRN1Qv7xhi7aTvAb3E4d8FTXJr0DF2w@so08O1oVbXrCZ4BI/PRG8MK7b1DuaaXd28rdmn1o@pNPZ5vDWsAuVf4euYzNbct3wuFD/tyKlR7pl3knQgg0P6h1bH3BAY/7kXLubagGDcLC@zj6dTRfi5nLpLaZ0YpXfngpI6Xc6yeAjSLg1XdEik35s/5nhrZ/2o6P/1/aHescLGho6se0FwQKyt44TiM4gLA/oJ08f7J6@OHq80ver@rC9gtIzTQcwUEY/1OFlfD1nTDMI08fgicHXVBIJG/pTcvnTdVHlEqjOPrGJ6pw3qSIJCHt1RTZ85Q3gwQfqIHx1Faj11bQnBuqbYB@0Glc3IZlqVcmVyDZ@K65MFJmmiZ/BLDHlmkFidbJ56atiKJeVOdmoEr7ME18ZRqgrn@l7B8CoqRoKRYQzhWyOwWczUORA6KeLyBWh889CBxUCg02UoiptKr6qC8jT5uXR4dH@yenu6fOTutyc@6owglLYNqQWKNy5p3V5KLyPN5Br2dcfqAoWC5Kjn1XCeWsvKBfBT7UtF626VLRFofhtjLN5aduSRLWBSMIc8ifwLDXqi9wZODHYQYlpBfmKYMpMMQfVLwJ1xEDzNE2otDKRVyU80kFG27R9/@tfNqS@@AXMMn4DExP2FfZDS@w7TtdP0TPI3VeQ4sHu4ePnx/skyOCi1VyY3fGgWsqx7zkwDUVQTz2Tbo@ukrgfJQ51Va3GD@KAmLgYJ2Wqv4V@SwEaOgQLsIOaX/zYKZLYpPABg/GwUqT/9nVpHhfxpE8SwsaDTMUhWWjztKFsbGyQU2gk5OHx4af7xwTzv/@QOiOKEAQ5ReURf/qjLvsaUaDcLfj6pzukAhVVjsVFFcgEWlUWil8Q57TvjtZ/A5R@/YeqVwk/OxR@N43j6FepoN1eUNWw13R2JqkaPfbNUl@lapAQbULBF0xwURnVoyKpNj0TlbtgHnqorXS5seM@VKokWCS7@IFT/IyqTj@NBVmf2GOmEdDXCxaDliaGNCdDNmlm2Ye0@EjA@NYGNPa2AbI28WwTRvtxmbyGlogLt2Wm/EcQavEbUQLQZWoSUD6LBLyh3tSTGq70/lf@mdSvEDCPwfxt3zyVH4Dtl3xbD8y/zMwvJWxoN9WhLvISzRBqUfZLwDIS4h9xH/muq80ULi0Qh1pbA8JKzCFU0znFOgZnKbCnAPR4ASdR/xQqDZob1JivaImlZ7jNBKpxLksSNimc/xEp02JM2Z7za@qc87l8VpEgk8J5AJB@f6WPyjQYwGSyDN2EOzdH1VdtaGpbW4THSWCjmq@wmpU27Zca/yrM6CaE5YBJgMzVCcSBKIsY4Ffzo8Hok1aSGBWpV1yJI@HqOjAsUX8cvtBu@4jgSQKQxXBk4Ac9pvgJ4DGIRr5a8jZ@NDfyba5NH5CgwJhETUme81UUPXXG0Hygky6@vsdUFOGZCzYEorJdj30Ym2oDx/Yo3uxZC80awUfA/L4mIg1goDT5@mgarVv@BYI4QRBlflXzrb8kjXHDbkqsbRJopj9Y0ZhtMP@i1F/TZlm5d28qYk5cV6OMyCI7J7aDs90HUBiSUCVVk5R8clGkbHZlkfwS@clAcVDb2xUkB2QKSEbHMF87I293b//wk2dHJzeUDdOQ8evBgO7XttINQczUm6EhHi3WcpU8OJBOnjw4CCpikel8hBoD4fdLotxWksUiFoJcHIq8XrRVObxeuvU5fsHUplzPr6beljUa6UY@FPlLpEsPJgkH9Hjx9cTV4ips5XK3ZWkBT4qA3mO6IW5kNZG8nNebIGrasfjNlrCiI7yMiSnsBGBqeKlNCRv7zcJhwcJP1p/iR0C9aF/UVvdFflNDXZaommbsnC20ffoOEY9IeYNkgERyohQEXdv7njEmfaGTVgX6j/mjI0NUxV8kw3n5NoxHQNGiAo/jIhVZaNT2lUkPQAy0zDYXqFZkSqUD3behPmmmFjGR5PxPQ7GEE@y8D5mWpyLdhZxIIrWjsDLkNv3UAbwkBx0aubujCYijR86IfSqE7jZ7aASmYwfI78MJm502yCeTIYTr0dexQVf@gXILEBkwGQ@zyngpoBK@euppGhWAQ3p1VFLtF1wcdnOJaVIcGNOu2QfankhmgKLdU5QmCVVYY6Gpymo7ztM6W9TCrV3xY9T4EUX7l9JjPl1kQK/roml3jWkifhFPlpuQPrrHL16cx5P8qrZE9an7Csa71xWrh9kvKLdTEn3s985Aa/kqalEq3aQS4HYdMFPwGXynsFQSBx5HvztbRc79ZOw@BiOwEYneUB@RxMRmylFFQq2JRsLOUK2RQo0pXrZJOk0FKnhRD5HQmD1qYuN3QrdnJCFV8dPE4OrZXXy9NUekrohiE8w0kSTZxO@H7gHHheqCkxwIwRClTMFWsQmBmAE5Yp1EZA0c4qA/hIUXVTG7wpt@TpEukDqIE1pqUrtPIt@DXeYc@VKp7FfoMlUsEWh9N8mhKAHYG3Qu4OsBu77eNMAZiL8iF1sQ8psUL0bTjbGMPPIVrkF2YhFl6YEeNgKwFqrMOwMX78S@DX0F@INy@fnpQauYlHgSKm7ru2YXF/DZJ0dCEc//SBx0U2kpaLzCJLqPMRqqyG0xzXCoqfWAdhj@GkmNRdHgqxkPhGVv0TYV5dZW70f0awFCZnEA8A@4twJwqNY4mAhb4bea2P/0pzFkNhKbinLWcs/T8ZxcgYdSyZEcubfZEITNulzd2dRBihq/mTZAJpdS2XPj4aDXPexLDZ4nGslKUury8jJ@kDoyX@ZIXuiaav7NdDbX8tqb6VxTim/ORkq@Lr6ZNvliNXPWbNSb5Ojos3etd0l@ej57w5NGAmTNvWe8kuVj5RK53M5rsbMSfjgdxJsz8hausx7BPzW/7UbMOprbPRBh4zyJNRqAcYUv8JJUjzfhT8X9V3Axwb9eE2vidvPdu2Rd18fTGTFNc@R1u3A7A@Ag1eQJAXn5PlB6FkEiDfqmEhRcueEUiN2u0e9P9vWZOTkY74gFsSiqkdmFrSefv/Cvyovnzwl5Tp4/f3u8Zi6imU4nBKFOzdNrfuWWnovhp8//9Mcb88zlUWvrT78xlIwNfD3D17fnT9B8ouTubWzce/Agm82oqsrMR58f/fzu7m72YSZ3VM9tZwV5Y@tP/nhjQ1W3VGmj6XlKM14/O/uMV@UsL/7pD@Oto6OveV5N@z@//q6m4KMAj3NSADoBl0YUMOKzCLeCPNaHXrG3MWjlSmxGf61Y4H65QZTaduG/f/fZm9g4VlOlFy68x7E3sXwxxoxgAJsW2M5jtdgWBsvPYzOpWq2CsfDf/x3Er30CcNBntgWPWi6AlZ/FakKVRrmK1fJgUFQV0v2/v/71SA4ZmahSNi64dkgdLj5bUPntJlwpem1xqBBXkCUpCGePB2PDIUrxvnIfLSZY4GUb@GURY9yIKcUsebYDIY/r6XS6KbYEuMSXdJJIUhS1oSj3gRwI91LVqpAiTOWvpuXu42cLknRKq@/AiGncf7F0xV78vVwrwVT@HgAfc7H8xs6rh7UalE6raalaml5@l6K9q1DkHWeHJxnyKg7CSL35ilQeo1eNl4sqn8lkdlqsa0wRa8I06CIxvNgzFgtdsPOSa2417PdNErqzWORmXBIFvTJcbB@vP/sPf/a9P/su/X2P3v8ZdQfbXbMnpSDQOXSOGlw75XKnVuNrLn/ZQHsNWpRcLpaLUmveSKTqteYxUeSPr@I5LX5CcBxQMI1GslGn8Ws02ZqfPNprsYVzjbnUom6@BwtMHeDtY4rElrFGzSHWCLkWDgZZ/5SFUD@vNQVkjapCXcnnmgKLVd@ByuHVQolvNWPC5gzojtqsqTn1GdmpsYsMNj3iYG40NR8UxM9vbVG2hc/CVos6xWpBtNoizJcN5@epxMXqdalp0JGhFmR0Z6O8USzny6rUqq2/KosYeNGghmEcebHzWHhViN8OA3zGwpYZcXsZrYmwWkjQgMlS3DvCQV0BiYCewf7RSw0vQqtLyyt8xTepLZ5UoH2omqD2W7ys8GFnoxP9cG3Aj/7hCq343KAuvjMNcvPaIGUlpWpS7l5@X8WB9o4rmm8OBgzSabfbbzttYD90va13dGWsT/SpPtPH7Ul72h53Jh3C@gxZlN7VnJxTdAKrKMS0nLIZu49F0tSSWsTPTmrFolZStYKiFfJaQVaLOa1Y0gpZrVAAgFpB1UqlrKpq@YKWL2r5vJYvgbsKYfIQRkMIhZxW0rjYu/oGOWZkrUnSwdVI33k9F8WWb6QGB29BcKYxLvYPcNUUVSEpGPpkeAC/R40gjuNPUTgSAx7usvkuVX@Xgh5fS29RatusCX4u4SW2dpppYT6vg7lS8f9btdBYoRczQeGa83R662UNWJuXtXoaQL70QYoCoUDFVo00t6hXmJqfnO@/1QTuSEhv1beqzh69RdrnhCaA3FrK5s5OWgTTDsSsbULfTqbTm4KwgQNu3R92IHCzlg7KA5CaCRLPOvG8s0Og8D/jDUIk0I/51rw2r2/N51tb8N@iz7n/Btf51o0/fS2uNWEW/k2kPY26VGtIDZ/@NMEuSjV0EaUGGGrwhnB1TS02ccRD/kVs/uP8i5nFM3TBLDdFyDUXS5FUDHXjarEUF3v1/ov/De/G@y9@D3lRAj@jzMUukVJIKZRkS0yghQexn9jkCbtsMOMdWNEFHWpP0NFmDxsXuyTplUjKbD0hoRTzSRGH9JbTa6G6HZG8gqBLpBWpKOHVYp5vpZWZSmJbfL5ASejP3bji8fg/eaWWCnE2CYT6Yl55nvckkstFPiFwRZUVQbmqsU@isK9X/dyq65/83LqLi12ViFEG/CQIQwwXg3YUkyRBqHGx2tYQDxThMoyAEu959TPh@a6AUzT6mC6yddj0Q/Vwv1oq1VD@MTaPaN9JPUzBU4H//gaUgjR6ELTRq3aGwFs3elpObeDnM2JC@w3@Hr/FHznt4O/4Df7I6Vv8HY/xR5608Xf6Bn@7bfydDvH34A3@nrzF3/M@/hpf0TSlwm9eUsSklZIy35zyFEEVGLFqja@M3VmZfguOV7dVEFj9SayEli0lY42vGNOOMRqX/dlGPN1ldMYVvVqqtKuqH9Tfmo4@ounhPn9chvInF8sqSeI0qFbKOa6A@yjhAQ5praQ4bvwn3/nGN@LValyI0894ZcFNaGOgNg0EVoiZZTnBzyND/qC6PS9e2Yl/pU4nGHKlZh09m@DBxapkU9lUZEvuyEpbaYPBJLJL5IE8ULoKFcRkg8gzeUbkoaN0wWTATwaTKfeI3CeyLdsQDHzBNG7JYzT14NWHXw8AufAzcYt@W5E7BBKykBWlXyxWWhhTvmo1uDqJE/6VAZK0qIiymDeb@JG1Ov/qVUNKNdVSkYjYrMVW/VUj3uQbPH54Qy1lSXtmbDRe8cBwyDxr/uhCYp4H4nklJjUaEkM8oIvW5Hzeau0/fdhqSTgSNohRS@@kgcDv7FSB4Puv7Vitst0o0/EiGDNi0tZ2o6YJaM6nYTRQ0S39Ja8FRHjXNmjJm68uXoFAk7hAsebiHF4XgeFFAx4tJvBQb@niRSNipQZJurhgoVdAWDIsGJnoH@TBf6i/@Y/r/@Q5SZJEvZlMXM63EvRK4i@ZvJxfzv1nLZlI@JbEFvzQAewY5XJeQyMNdAmmeiLZTM7nzA2eieQWA1iDZLZqNO4iHIwnsTBJmix7JP5@35C0fzXiFfKK39pyO1eNCu3@WblEYvyrCtEXG34ajaksJ4FE@Z8DwuVr/YruqkhW6LdgN9t1pfknP6SffNpO0kC5bKWipAizqFm1UskGtkKxUikGls1EonTzqsnbSh7koWw2maxUwLIdgJXBCnHr5F2aVEkDns3791kiRfXqKoCpZfNpGTdaVSpBSjlI1vD0DqPXwHIePqOfSwIykYsRpAbE33GSkOn31pCOx/kyf/9@omvgMY7u9m7y/n21JF9dhS6jETgpS06tVtd0Wy10166u@BZPN@mUcmCXi1dXilxKK3GSdNzEU/waLKSVEBRyT63RZEtApNVsAbz9HOS2tvLZWi2fBZd8ESJCoRiJrpA4H6/wsUtaDKVYYASMr6AziUGHhvHRu5zHaE2SbC6ZAOKXBM5xHsOfi3SSjU@5XLKSleXY5ZxngZVSiYVOkmw@UUyX/F91I0lqwB2xH7J4WjqbKqR2gFnGnzdddSEprVwaVWVevTTKONU/r8AI7znA26C2IeP@fa0EqCnKlQbn098qjEDIYMGjwcXjaXLvPocqmNx4ubJDa1Qp5kgsXmGOQhzoOCkCbiU1lVOKiAvO7KHuMGASOCaobZANTqVvfHAlxkttoCMIPjcoH9eFi3RJm/TxIn2UI4lJLHoRizB/@ux0wkAOu3zf0ErjUlEzcDHCi02vazmNtU4Yeo8e7@7tn2bULYHE1IPdvYx68vxBTEFrbmGn3hraj/d3Hz57DhGOHu/vnux/fPjp/vMjcPfIxeIKh4VgcAgHiYhphf2CvOBeu291w9CNiWG0LiaTizfktWm2TKhLawKFcvou8YwWlGWkL8pVgbtjevrr17o7ohd5/4Nvvf/B//D@t7/z/re/9f63v/eTL773Lbh/BPd32Ps7/7aUw@dPvvgXv/P@t34bHP8z3H8I949/8sWvf53d1P5HcP/XiNsf@XckHLs5gPVLP/niuz/8yRe//H24/5V/f//m/Ss/Xn1/75vrb4z33d@5Pcx3/h3cv8tgBWG/81vMDd83wv8WC/fL33//a/@e/f/E/6Hxt9//2h/hw7f88@//yX99/43/qKrFP/k377/53fff/Mb7b377/Tf/qfr@1/@NIkcfv/P@e7//l3/wu3/5B/8z/f@IPn/3Q/7vv//P//x///P/9Od/4N8/hvvfg@nHf/4foZ/@ze//AP/f/f2/@cMf4P9//dd/8/u/@je/9L9Qw28ww//zr/4te/7Vr/yXv/7Nb//lj7/@17/647/@jd//y//jl/@vX/8vf/U//t5f/bNvoONv/Pgv//CX/uIb3/qLb/7Lv/jGF2ue37r1@cUHuH/xD@Dy4fn8EDgfUq4v6/LFz5Sfvws2FqlAO4HW/Yvvf/0XoIH/GiHvv/UjPKYL95r/j1SFhvkRs/3/wKDeLDP6yGCC@1fff@s7iKL/CVAE/xBf3w4tSz7M8u2FBdD6mysi/eJPvviXP6S2mFGu0ZUkHLqLajGdAvEmVSr5w7e/yARRfmEZWgjAT@nbSKGW/L6NtO39D77@/of/9P0PfuP9D34JB28hW8rsZgTljhU6CJj7gHAYMP8h4TDgZ5B@K01n6IT0Z2Db@CxX1Gzbrnz22Wdc60rC8@A7V@Qz@JHPgoswLzwv7nsFfuiOB8gJuNdfvWrism7ETVIYcEllb98Ld91DSoJ6L70tKSrzMq6kTRaLVMBBK2qNSNalXi9Vhh@BR7mcuswI2w3g/GjUOWcERVJ8qBsSUfSMltJ0CChlWThStnfkbLqQ0nWQY9MIN015oFTAkeU0Mk37SU79pV90h0DTFDVOCZvPn1LvKTelK8TwLxBSJBohNvtXOJKm7BK98Lu5gZEa/HjB6jI1cjlIJr1YLaAsImFcWoq50DVzmm4WRJI0hklPQfYGA6SQBq8HIAFUq2mMWGVZBCsrTK1IaFbS6SqUG2OzOJlWEUFMH1AoELOaPiatVHXKIqYRXi1AR5pDp2NeUfl0sfoQEqxOHxKEhcAp2FevqrVidVpDcO8YdtLT9AOaJwRWTU9r78BepTAhHhd7@A6yUqym07UiJoiFZNWTabFKytHC0bKnSdqvA3jj0YftHULu8UqRZwslG4gwFhqf6UVoDAjBwb@RTvnFof/ASO8URfgGTcpPhTD/bcojbzO2GQMAXEEQRZHAjXsRtskOeE8ZqDRNFl5pBiFNWwRtAaEDwdmkNJem9ZumFkgfnC9cc2wQVc1WQNyoEHRyOxx@cZjubpe5zSlurbwkPossVwidkpxzOoTJyhp3eaX7JxQ2dTIHpzyHIViaqS99YWYRWZubm1ysxmv8M5FWjSQR96xMz5ng1ksUnMqEz5d4dDbooZugrBC/guUj77/@w1hWLsS4zTiuYcYJS4HcS7N7ZydF7gE@6TviNqXnOIS05mSdGIO5lU7zKqRWc9LcyxTiLpam0K44cVqlC6dpLpMhRKzG0I88e/bMzxJ1eFnl0tCpVE1BO67fTSaTGMQQxYyYyfhvkb6pg@gbROrrv8VNRCuJCm8KCPTo@O7dO6hwuo2tfAhiNPF3tKnZIvUEB6bpy7JmwcEsNVvi2DwDUfJZQhK0auFKEjyBlIA2muTY8QfWToIrEVeLIAxjSEC9mEgFWxzzChIXdtSLHvwmucKSFXITteK0IZubxqX68IwVy1@imEsGnnvPyN6zJ0/2n56Omk3C4Wd/J2OjNXKdjuF5CfTbffqQtUO1lE/G6nXEymlZRWLH7ZdlbI/pw4fHhydlwrDkV1CClqNCV7l9vJQULjYavdiK@TvCePx2q8Of4LO8QEVCLQEhTsZqXKxjoHQF7Q7/cFe4J17/gTMlCTnD8xklj9JuEldrIR8/70wIahZnasigf@P5GXFri2KAq10KkcUhdKiRY5VjBkGhBqKVioGhwAxKIY8B2K5LonG1k/1TAH36jCiqLHK1z8hUxKwJc65mVS3D7o8Hm7h9kW/IfKT0m3U5gz9V0@CpZPMZJVdobmxYlwIm1KDt4RL3oc7BeilggT@Ci3AfceQjcIJLmBMOd5cSf7L98FnF31@J6j4TbJMlr@Sg9yY5XDDw4XGj6AXkKHZtxY2LbXz@@ZjUavtPHwqHBzhrMB2QYJOhYHbFgUjbRHfiGtS3T0jX/NTEL/iKXdMbWfoMeiEgJDafz3sA6fCAqDWVWlmMLj7nHerSBvN8qnNAOXtc7H4wO8IV7pfL1XdKtgAZKpffaarKgQOXknBX4wa0HrolJCWxX8WDRDWtKKW4mMLz8NI0jaNtn3BlgyN0B9A7uVoVfDqbVegGIA6/EqVPq4ulfD/s9N4irCazsOgDHqQ/dokc@BWYn28LSDPkGjc94gZ2ruITA/n@fQ2ngbSsHBaTUCSQOVTYppbVsBLADVybsWzBX6Lieb4Z4yxjTLpVMMca8KiwfqjEeII2pFNaUeZi9Rj0Sq7erFf/v/8161xz@o/3D2ip16vcFIhb9PadMQx9k6Ufxz1xni3@z54No9Zb/8NnzpNnztCBPwxVT5DyVBb/SmXJevvfJ3pIXCowFnFjPPgkwy8r57h/9Bf0bNqk2eLolq@QvEa37taVUra5D12mTppbga7yGoTeYsesCSqJq/JYYGls@keva55h9UQ881flt0Y1TVb5Lf@rKLUgYq1b7TqdCW6yqnRF07YNFw91swjZLF9xbNQvXA1WIGGsSV5y/eoFVTzDGdW@iCrrXFu3uK7Ydroz0RvPLDw9ZzluNQ6iTzzwWEA3gCfG6d9tTcuWoUjiyBltc2qukK4rMrAXeCvFjJrZMLYLhXJX7FiG7m7nyrliposH8/z14e2cXO6Lnz15/Gg8Hh0b9LTedrYEEVDJK6pj3C6WczlosTyfrtNkmnW5KbJBR9jYADJt6F0B3rh87AlqsQmRu6Zbrcbj25qiCkpZk4tzboE4wPlAqWXl7JYEb5DTJFyWhgERcIpIVrakEVYfGCGIDsY2GHNbUhuMJhhLW5IJxklNU@QtacJqEXFW4zAzacRVBmsyM1Au/ZGibDu2MefKGT1jXlLUlnu93jx1mV5YOP1SYDZA@lzQM@3L0FoRIuHKZJIRzIUnuOg9qMNLf7W9zKu5Il@pVxb2Qp6vNOfcztDomjqe/GvIlzdj5WH8ZlBjkFCDcPOy6zjjctvoOa6xCKgp@SAgy9DNAFl@HibXkDHFy5vJ5SOBppc3oWRz/DyMFWSLm8@hMhm@obe9fMnFUsefarUaNIzLbEHN5rI5VcvncwUVeI5SNp8rQqXKeTmnqtALs6ViqTCHXiBJ72L0U75k7zLoHWX6MaOEXmbauOtNknz31LQui5rA@nEiWYFhLPaOi907/lSt1dZPXSSAR/tUFWpVLVcCk4YmVaODnqoKqiZoiqBo@L/DoOL/w8Or8FfxCbE0lTtFHX1PgXUCztAmj1HX19ghpw5@7bFPHhidNSH2Bjo9mLDnOp73dwjzQLfPmNdDkynGD70e6fjJW29ojgdrQjwfDVG9n@H@g0HYH7Yhg0g9WYAH8HAtx1kVoECeH60p5ZPwUzSADPYtGgh@fPjxo9PI@3R/d@8RlycPnj19eO2V8wPlyOP9g9PQWmC@QdRcCOLn9x8/vm71X9lnz497E8fFmzt49jy7eIROeO6dy8K1HCh0pkD8B1qpHAIsJNkAMSwwKByelrqfLZH7vjGXXxhlNL5gh/pNLzy9w/Q7lLnT4KS/ThWNtA3SYVoccaKJalj2JUWlUOK4EbGdC1KQSdexLN0lTq@3AY4DHU8tGyj/WBa2REz6wnGt7oXZNTaAp4E0SiBG9mgmuEcAZDjpUAVBwL2ivn4YBG2C67dta2KQyYisdYQXOqHRNfsDGLIvnCAA19Z1AveXvSC@Eb3GtzuMWRrU7YaPdTM4F@NKMZ7f4/lH@livuEbh5ZELw7bXN2r7U2iq0HF0d5YpZjR@nOMPSNl@merjGqDljFBS9Ub11ATY8o0NELf/6jd/9Ld//KvbakPek3H28snjrDoD1kKRKu3qOxD8h@2r2kuynXV2CEE2HqW@lhEr9qsgJxMQbMteLq9s4yjroXIPKgsRlHUIFWd8kUekkrNaKuaKJU0tZoqlYjan5HO5jKJmlEKxUAK4slJU8sVcSckUsyVgdLIl8M2BCMsEJimQkKRUGcDaHWvSNbao8C0OQMpmi/zkbUJPkpge2ieENyAOz@HEyJhqjUiZVRhOiSITrUAAIhSExA4O9uSDA55/gBbc47Qn83wXLbmiLBce8LxBffaKyLTxDotTRM3J/JhZZPkB1MuEAcCPDvH8AC37eZy15nkTLXu7BweYTg8tKsaHYGfMh1mswFKAYDZaQIyjAN6E0CDYLksnSzO6jxZMEn0OmM8e@PH8x0F20OeYBWMAHgUl3d3l@UNm2d1Fnz1a7BzL6FfRsksvnnfBAt2F5/tg6LvQUXm@DUbsNDzfAVNnpoPbEEz4XRp7rPP8jKEHEcTzUxpa75zxfCtwx2Q@9XOTQ@yWqUVhpd6hlhL@eF4NMo3BtNCi8Xw2tGShbI8efaoPxl2jz66Zy94dKOmjR5puTif7B@2PP273@213trv/8TF67e09At5kNnHb/bYfsd2Cy4FYe49U/Ww4u35BqQ9brbJurfT6aquV1e1rXq1Zy8AcQqw3kDP/6mNCw9YeeO09au3oqzZrUIAtpBdDeLfxejCE9wO9zbyCi3rR97Td5ivY/CWpkeBQJMF9F9gdz4D@2pmh3nGdCtqnVSJnkM2Z1fNys0I9yBBEC7kyR/9eAp86Tj4mL2f1aVVuVqfVgr87spfgG1M1Z/KZjeG2UsqVN/RtRc2mp2VUXOP04iQuKNskodxPvSWJp8ltFcSMDb6xvS3wdaW5nS@8RLJUxse2qhTLWVklSWbVCmWII8dlQvCRrBea24VceRG5UEjrklouFICVA/yMgSFo4wxgiyQSF4Z@lkxi1uksE5SHFpzMaKHNSi8xzUyrLJNklqxMq0qFfZyByNegJRJd/BLQpIMK4AkD2geA0225jBt9ErxSKvKQB0lKJIEIzedzhpzLLMgrl5fe5WVjHpJGCUyLqbwXXzs9Oz39jDKTNX9m7Mg1kMZVfOvHj/bEw2eBDT/uIx4gk@u44h7StiUfxu0GTqcguoiPYHgGwTJww2PErmOJ@3TrK3DKgUegX1D0Fe2Lp4@W4JwMnAuWMmphqVBtzXbHIPjtI7NL9GoNTHqXJGiuiJ68oIxBq1artqpDqqgEihjE@iqhHwZagDn0WN5D3TA0@iUerfU9WlV5DuPTNDYFOK0qEZRXQ6f7Sk13Kl385NGD6gOMXGnBu10xqobrOi4PUiFf6W3b1Ynt6T3jyHBR69Hhs01gU/C8baJHjOQmaexj6D2UbuZCzSX2ImdPJ8OELtTayWUnnCAOHRA5ia8Fhb6kR8BbVZ6fV3pVkngJQd@A3d0kia74ILmdrQCeHpBWEpzkV71XPaKSfLZChZgEwoIOR/GD5daT1dpXgbtioM9IuQy58Sv6DKBiYgAY6oD66MmROa90qhZJCGSapDjKVvrVOka/wseWAIyAINSvmlxNEF5wNejUlVlMr3qTNv1YHpHbiirnK1NwUwrZygBqV385rbjV0cQ1KhZY/clidthdrwBOAXUA5u1V4v0vfD25JeSqzK1CQV0hF9ESW9VpxUb129AuqloVPNL1rJzJFYHByBUywBio@YySz2iZbEYooCtwBZlcBhxBeALmJWEleEL4jDyVRSWjGEomIb8yu6@SmbOEDOWnSEtmxs6@PRkSdIGqwrZJ7fDWk2k1BajpOkTfEmhTBVJSwXIBzgdkZGYGFNKxoVssQlIgWiphbSYw0ObpZLRfb5bL@9PR18ArIbzZzqcLcvptMllJbCSrnvGGq1W4GpIdWurRBjRcfx6deJNhHSoZTEpBLdfrbSxiQc5osgalM1tX/S2@xjcz8kZegSqa02kohTCyEZ1HRrZo4TZqIVNvGVB1SkmtcCKd09WKqlCScqmczCaWWUxu5JM9xCRJNPhAsUMiHi@o8fhC8E3GK7iKtsEvVkOoOEy3NybiQIZJ/L6ay2/zwMTxZb6k8hBsQUXpcX45yDCwcXMOGVGSBTH6kptfzrdA7v8Kd4KntLfUl/grvHyy@wx/XwGnEliLL588f/b82QFHJLoTW2zFKhsVsdKqgEUQaztcrEwIENeGr4lO2iDky@7xTm/VXrJ3Aw8HAVyOfmajTpp076VhopBIPkUtJ9skDoXQ3WFdVbVmXS3AoAkEti6zoKqqVCAXrRgePxJrUEHTS8jfVrqGB4S/SmYzPS0ECL5frvXTm7I6i523@HxJY@dba4p8Rjbi91ME@CCBxM7PNmpqKh0/Kmvp@MO4lo2dJxqbtbQyi0sklVZnPdw0gpsPpDiEU43UPS0Vf54uF/uZspLGpwrPcpwIG7GdVmYnWfI4Wickdm2qY7e62z/erQS2vVpRnfkHm2MvW3yx4GexsQkoU9Mvl2PXYKR@ieszuD00XonHLuMkFp/H5/V4k4vt0OPTKjs@TWLhAWrctuGvOGrZPEnGSknfVijFvES43PeV@E4sjqtqZc97F6OtKjiT@tVXKrTxmO0EDiA94rQdjMy5HK4nxaRXI@9ztag9OXxmP3QPDC7W2LjacHAhMJiohuud/cnXCBkBiuOkUY1Nq1n/DIhSqwnKlooKIwukDKNMT8kL8lWNdaQa9cir4PP@F76fnW4Vwa7KCthVNZdWazUlBVxNbPT@i99D1V@X@5/uPiZxXAH62z/@oVr42z/@13SXaXxOV4VUrRCDkGhU8oXY5eXo8hJ4ijnzy8WasRuba5qAH0nRS4WUCKWRijoYWlKM4RG4r4KSjHlCzN9bnM8JiYQiqcmUVpST4HPlq/ZLqHIRrMGqKnXi8zk@Gds/NnOqsrO1DSXb1rJqZQPqUgmPwpPwt2V4Jaic4pNXV4SApVPr9vumSk2SRMrvhK13RNgi73BB852wQV5Va7g5SMED9MEaXgoP5uKSeLyWllJxAlIbqdXnlXkzTVcBqUz8MmU3ruGhsYGnvpadUjb8jJRHf4ZBrdTBA2tgM1KvPT6RSkpSt0upHS6yCkItxnpIyyC5GjSVlAS5TAVLeOwnCI3k@1/4dVXN/@0f/8pV66r1mQoSb6mUV9TYT3@6NbEnntGt/RQi3qLoKZBaKYlFjUxoCKVdwhTAmn6s0CB2QNCe2MjZs/CB7IvSLgF@x@zbRpfKvtw58mi0RltM12g3QYOlUA9MhkoGVLdfssJxAdfMOH@338lQGCSF@urrzSR3yX2EXsADEJAeKtxHC1AEZwgsy@m0PGvijuhpuQSNpzQz5D5EgRQ@Qj2uG1R/jT9aCEA1pdTNqCzLHsUa5efI0PA81AoLYx/3EUTxP@phzchIR1VLGNK0YYQSMQjNJ/Xo1iHtJqRtsQgt6pqgpWcBMoTljkWyQSDgPgIehmLBBNaGmFsQoALk5CNAAJQh4QM2m2SLaElyaabTlYXK2TmBSsfTY3qg5oXDaAiti2qFgsgVDAdOIIjgZ@SxXfg1DIxlxDEAwmCwbS9VEGUwOrUhs0j1MH0wKIBFdR4maNHI/fuLXFWrZjdJaIkQ/pk5wpk8Wg/26rwCsEAmvNct8xmCynwrgWvY7ADjaZpdaHUC0@JbiUQlPFrnHAf/D2602CKvVRX1qGAB/PpivaIDKIPIiHZWhx2yVSWKWkiSMPMdyHuHZooq2wgF3cb0nqh@FnjOIYc/jQUfaQRidRqdHfXb7XU9PwQY/Al@IQ@1PTJi4OvnYfockegdjoPYYSwoimnR0D3TBeGKbsoJVMkmNCWJ0Raqd2k@6MEZNUvw@EouiS8aC0MTeOuoEtVPZ4Oqcus4UKHeyLGpDlWq4w0PEEGLABrlq59k2Z7YF/hFVb9uaORojjyqehJbPuaY6oR1UFkWjYubXNouSOcBbjLE6IukM@wStUQStKFRNZl2CC5JI9EMt4FLRxy3LWMIWToxDHpm1StLUh@YtEmb6gp9YkK7GhyYMPLYnvSQIVi6MM9M6RQ/bSA4PTzayjQvxZCvw@7Hdsn4ejktxzkjlnlmsEnvxJLeKo@AmAKcdgYwu7gBsWXcxqVqGZxSUTIsFNwFeBWYsZiJxN1IzJI335qykWhhjV7REcyEWrGMc92O4JdeV5wvnnszL9B8R/W3gV0MSa7h67yqxlGbTajMjfN1@FWp@jgRF1NGCT7GB7rv0MiNXOOcoKDN4RgDRLMTaJHCXgyl/YgOALTvQc9Clbhjt4y6zyAnbjfRga7nE3ib3COaymFAppjQVyIIMLDqq8vQwQ@iYjm8cRcqRqQrCEhXoHcOu@CHWnf85ofxg9aNZqqueNG8yYYPDgcdmlaVsG4RWHIRC/YObM@06BvgmYccrsjJRoJPA9g0n@QZ6DD@9eistXOUlpTJTUgZghB8VAMUyiroSHJQ52nk06cceDzQPfZ9LF9h7sXFhUi1OE9cUzQ8/Byo59i6JY36JnDCjjQ2hiPJ8KDrumZHGgVwFyaBfQVYHA1G21PkZ6ul@zP25rieV/W3uyXiPS@Og@M5fu2yP6QaH1HVokcb1IFJv5TbSfi771j7U5uZy6D9lbH9CcX4HIEQgmCmmVmmkwFgmXbnLNO76FZ8j3PaIQE41KIROKJudTewDL3AZI56YQhnjHQ09GpbZ3SxGSDxbO55kTQrYRByFlh9@8jE7a62cUF2XVefJah/EkNjA07MKNtDZjDsUx8w4rdDLpmib3NanzWXok/D6DCohfs3XFTnyF3eDpRpfUf/KfOfgv@U@U8XiQbJ1qdNxpKh0xyLg60e9@0GIRHMLAgzZxrSFz4UMvDhRGEgMORsyW0Od6dKYwf4Zjaox2rQMKBNjADhRkKqv2zUG03bMy5SzbTUh8bOU0RAjQPoepPi9KIbmhH71rk1crwlp/@3u2/dbxtH9vxsPgUiO20ypm5O4iRy5I5sy4mmEzvHdpLJOm41LVE2O7q1KF/USeZ3dj/sC@x@30fYVznvcD7tU8zWvwogQUm@pHvOmf1tz8QiCaBQKBQKBaBQ1YfzZ5qVNN741DrT3CC8gjYmHcSMIfSK4K/3tKcNTUQh0A0mCNDDKBGqQW3sRt56EmaAE4lxjnIpjQWxI43MMWtfOkl/I3VJSC@EtQEdW4DwPWkSoUkpyowcCf5spMOH0YDymLx5jlfbg9/I5eNlouTUUBFZs86dZGGVzxs0iexQV6vTTTHp1BVHU0lWM7/p/rfRv/fd6HdoXMzHnhlWJox1xx4qsO0lFUIPF6aq2qha/UoYFB8E3XBEM1dd9FM9W1M1D4pmmSH1oAnxZTRunblW57c86R@@QJ3r5yoJK0yqVWripCrDUsaFIakQPCkW62ITwwi6vAgQglGaWyzUxa7sYlfVqggOdXVNsUsLyStG8kqKSO6ra5A81sVo9dQw0wu655i0Uxgf5wheWaZRUoOGORUHFyHO93@FT1ucZOg6U5nDXKB5CCo2@Kx1PLf2IwtpS2hNAQAjzgAgLSQ4744rzrTAK@eTt0RGCSmNjJI3zQYiK4jBWASvi993N2EyXgOTwp9b4XmAxm5u5cjJlXk7Gv8ryb@cbz6af@XZj6VsznL2Y8mf@t9/yMdjUNYaoJb2US49gkDGSuZdXztMtnWORVU7pwUOaXUnlwPlzlG26XvxXBctnnQHJ8VeADsdRJeXr4XhxDPrB5znqBfDwTgYDx49qsiiKWK2m1e/rBmi0/4AQSmt2A@k67UHYdxfHlOntgan/SgOfQW3vJ9DvewIdTQax9aT9eMgdhxtMibLWIAWvoKq22xG/WjcbLqw2/QqySUENuMEey4vO1j/0pNVnsSTBro3dAcnv4atsXc7TAQy0cUOo9Znd2@oE@HwpaZIhrVI/6fUM9JgVDxIV44cJAGq9MnY5VBEZ4Pe4JS0vvO4gB1YZwp8I4UNhILhkHHxVYAlbcUKZ8OjxG35gaeL/vTdRdVPq27gJeVXswAyxPDVaJrGoOxoTnXNa6uTYqa@g@/H98DG9@BmfHkVPo2zLM2rkvh9VT90UwiUMUXj4e1ooOkkt9oz6GRQST5Dr5ICd0axzXZwbWBao6w1nb3QIf7wk7eY3hLE319H/5s70BSv37X7Ahr26mBC8qYHm2xx1hSbY1mXsjc8yJ7Z6hLW3r5jXZQXIdx3oEKQGsuCqw//7jQwEfQtTmIUGcC38DxMz2b4nu3RqpI4B6fRha8@r17fRdvNdtgNJmHb1Tl9C65p8T4t2Fhe3a3hEHQs9Aay1nNp7vKSVJrGQXTJVLmGZQL/wvOuZyvJEiXcwzvljGHjevohfUY0Y4uvKrvVtA5YXl7EduxFhO1PBLuTECJdCSKr5ajMP9KT8P9yO0GIDjJ7lv20Wu8m8bnvJk26w4yQ5C1kmwwP/wYiPLPN9uH3kej2llLnWoWqppedbPCs@T0e3dTjFlcYnpTjprux5G1Md2ees1hNgKUibOv7ppAZyLAlabVcG6J8ubHHBv0ZmYBvvE/Xv2ZWac4RqElJlnTjiJfbrF94DlbGDfrFhtN7@gXA03DcFIYybcOelo7LrjilFwwtrUV/ISWdoFhUFJJrNKxcjnmm7F@@JXW2rq2zNVNnK1NnMgKyVVqZnFamSt0L6J6buqAbdsbXSGckYe1MPzeJbfqvPwhG2K34shwtVyJfLV8sV0ggL4fLlbpLQnm5vVzZ5od4uXLAD5@XKz/RQzq2lr8uV8ywQIYRvfLDC3zXIhzvreXKlut9c8bB5zA29RaWK0mfUp4f5ZUpQqRAu0lrxBFbf6CbOR6FNLGxUukrcEzsY/nE@zA@/yvR/yUcHgfKQiL2OB9wZrWiyplJw5oxpB6aNkwgljkjuaJn8/reDttiJVlQzQqt8ewyDJ7U8MXlrDASxJDKJxr0SwhCblbmY6SsmeyO6OjaiUO5k7P1S7BV1gfaLqcfUebjtBKOgajLm/7KgpAOvBueKHwdnjPomOoYI5zJenPQAlF/Wb6hUejrLC669@0e4r3ubCbCNm@ySC8xWEumkw7Hh3McrnYwzDIJp@I2QWSX4U05GZTg3qliLBX0yLwmmT/rlkEw2IPfu6k5VjmglhFBSDwqHcsoS@YFlsVISmWdpanK4CMULJlDIzxsfeb4ktv6kfOJuPF5rrhuGjJlpUqWXFkxSYUL8Gd3Hoyl9mTxWoeXu@9bvpqSV9hrcQHAKpnUIvJ18B36@0D0d6NQGyJMVTBPsZ4/lc6q1zfOslOYd9NqZzsQib7a9uYqR0kNKclpdWBp5jfx2oyKD5MPUfKl0gT6lLZvyJasCW6h2/TaQmBBSxhdZD9@XqWPn1evJ9SsRtK9KBilpYCaNBxpeIJp2rSbcZWGz@tipPD@dtD97g4eZTvY7jzA4waMpkguo3x03mcrl3Rsk9iWLxCp5YoSQc7HpUk3px9J3PPRbXJsSx/2mvvbe7uvP9Kk@@TJE0/P0ZMUP4xa7LUm87hAZsPuZD6Ys2xZ9REEDofd2I6Pzwaj8b1P/dyMLBFhTcoA/LoY9tNj3NOyzJLnU2OXyklei6Ia1ud0GAQZqQRVJ8CUHWm6jokg4dh9EGggRr0levu8WvM43Fmz2Q96MPzH9NVswnip2dSzGLrGnIh7f1@8VzyPRxxJW2L1XToOO19R23vqw6vaoTp8VVc777Z@Uh/33qkPtd1D@Mt4@27zdWNL0b/67kFdORkTPMQ1xYKS6LodtkIO8b1aKj1SDHlrMJyI3HG3PPl@EPTUq0ErxDHV8zjovTiTl0I/HG9IqTotRyfYw4w4jm0vGsPeggOv0jIWyk2bb0DiioKivCe0pu1hzdsbtKNORHkdrH2HURibS3OqG1EPkrw118x9UZIQY5VNhzh2MiywLql4QPlxdkNgArG/AomRQ4KytgtKEy7577speFjff3Og4KRla293u3HY2Ns9UDt7@/T69mNj9yXRs3FwuN/YfIckzvhmb7ux09iq8QdBoFRQ8J7y63k8vhGFArIzVVqfcfJdGFL3J2/ZXW9o8Ooy4LugsVo@70P6REE3@j1sL6875zHUF9w/5aMC5S7V9l@@pzlfhb/hhNMcBbP9Qe5dzHF/l0rqOddGg2WDxtu6Hq407eXLHp9H9CYKob/CdXaV4vKzrwxwNuJpR6HKbcFGBXvf4lGFx7IBTRXdI9gAZQxWqopD9i0v@88Z5AbV1uoO4ChYahMjQv2Coi@Mqcm6wxTTtjIAirsWjT72g8rryQfie/qwqqsdjySDeph8kAzqkXyAKtqA7Yh6rHOcj/fOIZ7Vmnz4tTfc4WNh9ST5sBnwKvapxkn6jbs0UEnIU/iX6XJgRtnl4eDR4lkIRWLOj6CF3a4MjFDC5ZJMlKNEtm2jnDkSNh0cNWizNwlDj1TiBtgJBZ1xrNyqV1CHMA4K@5GExDztBn0xgUpNd5j31FN4IKvqq@ZREkqSb68MB8yACGObxSMpt621wvCu5ajk5kyNgbaR5HDOxgTtNgQ2ZxD4I2AIUD6z0mnxTMXXcwFm0NGs7MYD4kjs2/7Nzk/s3D5vhZkC2mrL/TX6/XdPE9nPrJOMnSJjR130ezgitZKPMjuDEY1xFqscfA9SsHU2GI4j6UM32wI@ceJpjnJjYqPafqluZGoDHaZr7A/6VqUnxMXX1HpCTHmXWpnj5ew8EV9pVHbifJqExe4O6AQng4vQOjvzcYh0GWL7hRRhPivH5udkzJiI/umksuNvCsGcn1Y3tjc/5f/2i4@IziIWJKC6MTrEP2JM1EXDg8/52GBxBL1LjzQTiTM@P0FpbYOnpSVGuQFG68CziNZ1L5rrSZqYG89@x82e6e/88evXqpTKQzKJRD6Pz9xUuvnqyFTpc5ljpU1ALNlJyJKsd80Xn2Em8voFrvOgF9aJIn3IEazbp@JcahFiWndy3iHJosON6@5O4Htqgy0qjCIpPijs/ij@7G5WVza8YmpQoixyukZE@wZy2fMssxSer2bAbd8MjuT33cE9vRE7mR6@C9r2jdC@C7f8yvWwZFqyYN0d7N9uACuT2x8CS233rwcsk@QstITTE@b0lxYTa9qba/xlpu947BEYzL3YQUmAWrWd9/mI2rjcd6WAZ4NJFaKDw@36/r7KyfqEypLcw5KhrcUgYN9Tb1Nr26jPwq6QKE3JYjlRnsyXjEWb@e@mwTyXeNeICq2D@JoeibBI7uHQgu5KpJ6eWViFYOt7FoiGclnsvhgZFB9pwN9oDUjIpp1mNdCZ28xFmXyi2DYC13TzRTe2bfjZwlrmbgTxHk1sQLZNUHCKmyXz@@@D6McVU48oWPD9hAa3SZOm@YbWCQdU8ZAyFgrZHryhW0yXwsheFOxFQzsYfpWyGvafZyhmJFHCRRe2xLpWjjVqoh8vGTWHDRIxDQSw9NSJYtFMCUbE85fndod66aTnZqcgUjIR1vmFzRVU/PibnsKYGsk8WU0UcnusLTE2RwbLY@zOatjr12e6D1votWnxMF0VSdsbq8r/Y6qSWSJTk6H53MaYRIK89vjxw9tgT7fCFM//Wdgyh0zLz3FvSOv7FGQ8iXl7nzi3seub9JQBbiCdmNabATNVkFSdOXNKpu08Gdn4ES6yL0TIIGAFImVP1@qpqync5kOXGcmGzllm2mAN4aShMmpmqP/t5uogkG@t79731yeDDZlgOvgNVvlvBqM4TG/lWU5orE@4lp/9Fo5Gfc4m95l6gOLyNaYbL9vxbTsxeJVWIZHP2@yWdPTtJDG79c1eA1fC24uFy7NgjN299entvXx53W7qTuN1XT1gj6ydzF5kbpTzLNlzL@rfhADLYN6XwPTBd/juxxX6Rzj4BiSRiW/zuUwb71bcmCKkNR9xHDJtFqpla3m69ztxK@jDbYmfux@rnP8DFeRd2PrejjdvZ720nilPyMXDvkul/Fy@kOOi9A0buoCUBSG9ie/WhIWbGsZSEtdrTgewj8LBVnglu2dsORkUy09La88cbl3fH/u9o2fH/oNWNado8g36vfh8dNn@fDo4u@iorhr@enLVmvz@m1KPH8Hbu1r9Qbx5l9eqRXZa/ETBEfyzEnOuRvBH9kyOYO0FiWKt1LJK1@Hr95THD7xoruCGxBSXqgc9w4W4Yjeu9o7Wjqv9amm9d9Q/Xsclv/FKdbxSXnHx4QeaRUnGyMn80fgYc6q96xr2LxQczXKMZH01RPHVEPryJhhFg9e13ZeZ3TgoANgC07bevKHO5snOAqzZcPek0A8vXb1N5itwrAMFyVngW0FlXHfn/WRsx7Qjwox6xSdtNr7ivxPPWSgVzofjAacYr5RgLfU1@uosmGtMJd5RoCxHkfFdifsFBCfN4@JgSL5OxIo6XxZ1rYy7k54F4gglWRzmPuVyuFMIRPVdrqNjJy6EQesMSHRJrf7KxXA3GW/EanGBd/FgyhGM@MJE6RiPOAChnyGfNqAK1txjvvbhUPPxXsaDfOE9qjHfk2EDeYc1RaTA/Ft94ftNXP45EUAIvyA6V0FvcWrNixRJuTvImwvw4ZZd@OOYAdcqpVMW0FjAlvqqKXC2FGcaoVpNJvq@cAlyCq3oP92CfJnfZpqR5PckO5OEz6n1Wwxacpdy0gZ@umkx1yqWN8VMZosUC7dSAztdtDx6E9KwmqitsNslpIUWCyk58Mj3e3X9K0n98RHqPE6Ql/T8THo@k16QdEEqzVWgCT7NVLEz5Ra/pPm@qVyazZ@pq6pYeSlQT7cKpJKkeddvyhsXxoNmlGbeSLpSuDJJeJ5JyFspP8/pfUm5lymTMHiSfiTpmr9Xdc8nWGbyvsjWj19Hd1DIxrPa1mSKSwv9qPujTFpJCtgsR9RUSopzAFdlBlVV38HU4oQ0OOzz87DdqKZQVspG4vCYyW08f5EraCXjR3caDbnFODOw5owRi0pc5woT7oovLFI9nHzPAsEwwWjKjNwNU3iiC08ssMh1z1QrtyBnBjg1bXqIV3Ev8iv@mMGeRc7kW5yfuCCYX0nj5XZzlkAsdO/l5pMpK01wXUQ@6kbdMIukdU@mIc4XErvWLnBSZyh3sDvYBr@XyAlbUBhJMUP3JEVTOs1QNux7XRci8Zvz9@ID52VAOvawG16pGpYZAd/CcjIX3MdhPI7hk4pd48Tnw2EXp46s8F3yFWodRWL1MY5bUojWzF5wGrDskfw@nvSFdCpUUHuAfAkDkTQhPj89xWUy3IAdXEK0YsclGhecWn8iGxo0Zh6uyjXzUMH5BgvgbnRqIyE9J6MHlI6HQSssOKSjxaT9ONLUTqTjHvN@Ou6NwPMZTWkVx/mX86j1eeslznOflEsPyxbJLvRxcKnw8FF6wYqIZBJW4eLwcfmR41hnwy05G84DoK9eY6J/T7wZXoT9fujUaMbgjDEprXE4ugjbBcfZD5NDYMAFK@NkEvewB@ejlmzukNIVEDPilnDsy3EYcRh@MT/LcXGLz8p8B4dW6WkzdfVF1AYBzY2TzgCnw3xgATcBQg8U6oVjIsoDT2VR4rNnjQvrLj1sRBE14OfEOptIyNAfjKMW9QzvZDldAiXHIGll/fYUJlRfqxvgcnBhHgK4HpNSwCBgjpJuwsHRh@bfhYPSDTNn7IHpmSJJvwGPFRru4Sgi6ZsSmHuFi1m4UwcfvmocqIO9ncMPtf26oue3@3vvG9v1bbX5kc@4cVDODobVq73XJF2S03Q5Nd@jD7naAZXMcYJT2/2o6n99u18/OFB7@6rx5u3rBkEj8Pu13cNG/cBXjd2t1@@2@fSdIKjdvUP1uvGmcUjZDvd8rtUUc9Jyam9Hvanvb72i19pm43Xj8CPXuNM43EVlONWvqbe1/cPG1rvXtX319t3@272DukLDnO3GwdbrWuNNfbtA9VOdqv6@vnuoDl7VXr@eaujeh936vmIjAauVm3XCsrZJS1jUxO3cbuzXtw7RoPRpi4hHCL721cHb@lYDD/W/1qk5tf2PvgZ6UP@Xd5SJEtV27U3tJTXOcW@hCvXL1rv9OtwmgRIH7zYPDhuH7w7r6uXe3jbT@qC@/76xVT9YV87rvQMm2LuDuk91HNa4aoJB1KJ0et58d9BgujV2D2nOePcW9g4edfIHIgxhWaOi20xgmEGgtUSkvf2PgAo6cAf46sOrOn3fB02ZWjVQARYVW4d2NqqQiHhoN1Pt1l@@brys727VkbwHMB8aB3WPOqxxgAwNGGR8JNahSt9xq9FPhJc8ErM6hnN97k7V2FG17fcNYK5zEwccNDS3MNm2XmmaF@BM2NpEiQbYMwh69sZKZ/bTRQjHmLM7MvP3aBKPSVt723WakbWTq1ya8I5mnadTrpTsNJppkkR6zbisaYcn56fNqN8Z4I5pUkw2PnrxqY/QXR5iDX1yboicp/dXuMDiYrP5vtakhe5Bs@n5dymZQeO2Enob/KZcnm4jYlFg5Y2Nn0pF6P48Q6iNH/RBJxvq4QACOYX6P4jpW9ALPVUstkNdDJf3AdhsHcVybHKGoxQSjXzZEUGS0ip5Z4LfI80OXNA14AutJvZJYRnJmQYx/el/TV9kcrA@kHSW7a5iEYtYRiP6PTTVSCXsEoH/aI8EUYerLMRh@PnULdnVYc1fOB0M2vAOq8tw3jGtA09d75biJ@HpVPH8dHlGlo@ddcSF2Ky7WYVJzp81yZTul8KIW@biT3PMP57BRnw@YNeUq@LNar1p6f4gxWGR5Cvt2gLXK7iTofO9qf218QGrudLqo/Wp76@S7zK2YC8I37o04R1xuWP@eXUsGWiAsS8OIkmkPWQUi1YZY2@SZL6kjGfIdBm1YflDc/VZyPM6kYQU2fOga9eJ2XgUXdnYkxx@uV97s/luZ4dEJ7B99PTxk7V1J3G79Vdffj@iHvZyy17HhjSPk57GSdYo2SLFh0eK5Yo8ZX9m4GIRGeGY3nQaf4Sfh8RuI2vJBEGG5saIGNaHiV4uBB1yih1w3HMMv84dmZoB3ExTPbSmF1yxih@QrsQ8oI1ZuhPutSv8Aexk@JshnjRIM5BmMfb7S5xLqwuWe7kdYyrKixt23IMshZzhY3HjltCAt7rYfha3a/lN87bVi7GYMmK8crdzSULi3jQWythV9GVkv2U/I3oDmL2H0Ze/an6jx4/awR27uwvicW18QGTcSUpinzrdjNaNPtKQjxEoBE7VTE3PFXb5PY0Ujz29nZw4BrFGA6OCIDmw8c0CXk/8iExXyRawL5Y99UU4Fc47AGddc6x@J86d1xwNZd34D9HvxiuFEliJkxOh2mVSh2OyfEz8WBhyZsj0p@jB8P@JNJkD/zmtOAl6Si3LCeCdKMlQhVa0fGWiRJfmoME63UipaX/6mIL5ZnfMWdIwfXpzJfdriAS6dybmw0d2e9hx5xAATI6NDXv8JiZpZwEtnV7kPF0c5yT9Vm/oKj1XmKliBm5@7dhntcs3Zyt48ZQne01Wha@pqHohC7cTHvW0ZJpayqv7cU7Aecb/R/EBb4AkA5659EysVqc5q6RHmZED2tWSNeG0E49JpJZ@u/bU7oGyXGRmZL8@@TKEItAbwGe2nRwxZaDEPDfrcZFnYnXIXvDgyxzLZEw@2mXdCRtidkPAud/mzRAEVRlfYoLoCnR21ZdCU@59NhRBJanVYepnEOLWKxBpeVq9TLDnnUlwaIL9u7741w9lV8vkKIiDD42hfV2@oN4EE0K5e7dmC4sVHxwMfNguojLZltDlEUCmNRiMSHUM0G7C0Y8mXkF90JsOYT8@H2n/hTSfRSO9I2GUfqoGapOs3nmaEf/1jFocjXFboV1g/uAm9UJYiIp7kqv8mnKJeQ2PbphNx@hqpazc52nKc6IJuyVlIj5Xa4iky7mEoNplaMgUjOJkccE2m1wPzh2S4Xc5GH3G3A8VqN8O24lnUgsk7wVKJzX67OOxNZamDwcx72hQV2AHJKFEWTbSEkNVmqOfaHbSdk251DsmfJdyS76/noRJjbUUVZQyrq6dmG8tT50JKq1q16CJs9Dy6mNGZd6C69u1izH2Fpo9tla5T/1EpFREiajeN6ojnkRuJk8f8aQ3@av3Y4we@oIzbq2CAmHorDhXnZVzjB9sCj5E4aht74mSJtMOhth@46XPoM@8aLYOtdu/VjCOwwmtAFrF6KrIMJruXwZn/ebWoBucRoMooHUavM9ficTD44Qf0WGno8FlzLGRJEinlak9SZ/Fv4y4YcN7ci65brnmisfh0LXNFMajSe1M3ETwzjmMANMwvszfw2kfaUmZR4/TQk72/inb45W99WvLPizPKywn@gCgBdzGlAWF3CEd88Uk6/Lp@kyGk5syWDieqLwKvGss9jIYPyMS8TFMBmODzIxZgt0IrMyuxfiofeW32QfhCI6Wwu0QMXtilz/7AaK0kxT5EZYCFVV@WrKKyinKFfwQ4mFyPblXn/yTsScE/gT65YfzuGUeI7CI6xhvS7GsV7SXUcKFzQMjltEsiUmKRadR37p@yLEvrqahZpMn11GDLX9IKdJu9ma4EiPSpYUPQvi5TRI5zYmHSWVZLXvstwMqSG3slq5n2PA2@1ke/DjElZ0zCKYtDdm1kL6OVC2iEiJKT5nX2iiLT@XbR8zq6l17bYqA1XkmZ1bQdDdnNBe@gRLJ/IpjrcGIhHFuinra1GM5Hg@Gy3ek3rWyY65ntnm0bnnerYbAwmxVmiwftJm01QkeJ@vOND5TTJOlGFuaEQ9h@crPCZtPE/Gq2sR4qzYnt9DhOpqldlPJpJL0d1vGPibFC1j0mokmGVKMO5yUriffj5rU8Ob1EkTDlOVVkyVGEyKjOZFHC9QUmRIq3Z1CzH0a9yl6tIlyqLdNtLP751qiThvJGZenJinj5BL0hON2XNokuTTswPgCbuJEw02EVKJwXvkTPsor50/gZBgJAhBacZhP96FkBzftrCk@4ugAHbcJa6EyJBE9bdgWDonT/4Rg7JVfb@5oi4fmJF8@XhdIVwkkWlVwrpsgmfvm9HrUvGIoM6SgIT6HFEmLZmTT2d1b9WfbQvkIgpTmZG3pW/LRGE@tEDb0x05qXkEHTqvSJTMjKjsQmiwaaCzQKuW0G8pyFdpfNBKOh3WDHka0gJDPLn5WdAm4814rJdRGkav2BFk8TW4ZbZ7Kb0iRlKHkHeTXQ1FUXV64EoBQMKby1TJBgFtTxh6HAux6x@a8DKK6j6hgtYxhSR/ZK2pq5zknHUTVGR49tnKU5uV4ZsPIzwVCisX8PCkipLPMz5JCoYluLi5Wjifz25PmIIXY8L5QnLpC90qWhknPCQE56HbJSyXKUVn5Jc3BnPjosZdJTPibU5@VrNTSdCrRJ8HwKF@eTn1ayqRmql1dzRbNlCR6eHatmUQihWcjnEiFP/cfX02xXZ4nNqHWIiOjZWj7bARFp1UmrdsKv8bqOV/KNjqGgWffDDfLr6aEWMk4Zb/ZAbta5iMD@G7/0601lqkGEx0rgP3SmcsuriwIWWPNYapHs7DSNZ72EgcFZk076Kj3hzs7GbevJxNjaNQLR49LpRKY@MR2fm9sq7GVFA2K2dzFznm3Wxxe/mX0/qTIsj8MOSRAxaygQ@oSGhRxYTA6lcgQwIGyIndeX2TFWv@807FDMOCEEp1H3SY5tTcExRNQlBi9vD/kDSAGqSfYX9BAtO8XlYy@y0AUTQ3FHENRaZgEX@TM6RmRBx86sM9OTqoYGASzsWaiecurbnzBDILIJtxZ7L7Y@5KaJ@dehd3uwFcfEF0ZngIWvk0X2NmxC5QkC04Y@Xbvecz@aH0VXkRd614xsti8DnBmYjJxJoxfePjG3w9P61dDN3f0c46mFWryCpq5Av/Uvsqd5jztLP4OYIUPCe075e4FQ7fFdJrOTFO9HsHpE2H0sOzPXftksni8J6ZpdntuEHU@ugV21kBN91gXML7suXu5JddkT4ib@3RV7oCGJYGhcYLPlbuVwFWzf55YvBh3OneTihwGQDr2uySiREL5cwKRzwB4BOrhR/SEF@2f8jSsd6YcioiCg2Ads3IHBZoo4Dj3W9XfLt1araaWhisrqlbbpId8XtU2a2obHzY31Ta9b@L9h@rq48frInO3vS/0cdN8/KY2CQbvcK60zkbb9EppVdwbg7U2unipWF3y15ea1ecb63HxqLaJa/309O//9b//@3/7H8WafvlfeNnkl6Ofk0yFQqG41Pqy9MO3dbwfbR8vL50cLQ2Pl0/XwWV/Z6/hg8Y4H6Tmo4XRibMos4D1le1IzTqbvc/oosrE8usFo88kXSpqsRUXF/XXWCJHsYxdbIXW9xD3KE9oCW@CDkwv5R0EdesFE2zHU@@0Qhjg0XxDlCRcYAcq5eVsxWzcwx1MkiE5VVnUnnhYZ70Icacl9aSAu7g0Y@Wjfhz2sQN@wTqvNM9xAvqNxk3Nv8Wf38Snm4Mr9eCTqx6U1ANfPcjl@Ke89oy@ekvFCLdzJRstB3I5n1LSowWYGao4YkWP1w8ca2eK3I6zxCF7AMm4qeDMcgvOT1Z/fFlGAq7Fp84CIn4q2SLhQyYUWfyy1P9G3fKFcnzLZa7asKLQ1KsYrsw6UUn6FypQEIshQFpzTwhSGVCVOOnjG8l4Kpovuq8djibEgEHW/Zc7PO7xgeaipb62ec6spRDmiM3n5SvmxnW5DM1oI0XqTxHgAxVZTpb4JuHy4rIjVt5WK7mZcgvbbp9mPrF1mIRjY5suhf6mLCYQa26bcEt9fa9FG3LL8YrKRcnxilVVbtr2WzlWkd55dxwN9XUFrh0D6ktS2zcZSehRBiRwxGd/ZXaE8UaB8RQ11S0SLGui2gM0XUZCX19Npw72CnJyZBGh@LNLY/vr1Nj2inxLxLCD8AAjlZjydYKoG2uvKyMm9mkwOkF0wKDDAdXGcm7G@3mI2jqF8aCTIF1gyGxyno5nasricBSc9gJfLe4ODkfBpEHTFmk@41bBoxbCBROQwODTVc9rnkFYWqS7hCmSNIUthxC8oDvR4dGkb3PJnRN0qRkK2u0KBkGGnZiS4ddMX03RMeXq7@gEG@UZ4Z2cRmoRy5IXlkYaUs6@NsPDbGboOKYGe@wkAyfnCKrJyDS8oAudY6Lt8cEvSfIufATounP6FqC@irD2DPVjdjoN@0Fmchp2HXPRv7iuZF7EeOZQlGKN5GgoT8ppxDtgRXrkz1kvEDI3GXdGzoLrLnyKdTi3RXseYSffiS1@MVBREoCOA5jxzRD1rh@JsJyaodIYGAXVYMt/gtDpBqeE3@QymIAVPy26P94rekc/f@ofP3A/9b9@@t1jTLRINrNsXi3qw2wjsfRYoZmx6GdejVVabFwNfupnM3zqK7nDYpGAECm6Rz8Xj78WCaFPi573oPhpUQiS6TJgUry5viLAF2fQXMxiUVx0FrwHnul898eyp2hu5V/0oXzw5JewMItK3qandc6oQ6D4nu5v53LlJC4@XS09Wi0/opXQaXiVH4XnmG/z8flJeEWqRIzlLE09n37PcEOGEN@u4mCdPl5ROyWsidw9ifUlJS1C9TDnepyErahMQXiC8hOV2V0qrrh4SZ4Ah49Y8PuKWM7kZV9QYjpocZ@L@TMe9FBPEEOuTd8OEY6ElYHYiPAWah6QTfCV6zjUM8Nlme85FdQWfLcyEOre4qI1W/QH/bxW1rzC8jqUaNya6T4tPS1Nj9GZIZoZoUtamVq@p8obPz75t/@599vieHFjtfhhRL/jxd8W154uyiM90NtD83axuLH4HNnWvi1OirQGpscn//a/qfzGXwgOUibP6c/GYwNrbbK4ka9yka@LG2v0UF5dpXr/z7/@K7VhSVZsiMW61PQVI7ZuKLIV9Jl3KV010EpZli6nYoUvZgGGWBjS2pxeYBh1tfq0xNt0i9qq4iLUnq@MPYqe4tkwa8ymQrKTYewpSDOSAlVUkBeQxoSioyzbDWO2AeZN0VS/3C@sxbQC@EWbcyRVJqYb92OYDC3Jsog60JUaaT0vDxulH3OJeUclZ2xK1o0KiaWdlrVPH64TO7wdhOOolbWSMMO11wouw5MC@LAQts9pTdWPu4NfR8ULYsleefVpsYPN/SLbcReHDCk/nBR@J0VQBwOihSEbnfpqRD0w6MGFl8/Rgkih30nOpEw8SdKyh2FL9rCyMYkpi9zx8@V4GM0ppKq0y39JgUfkTB0I0oqV9qlPJff2Kyq3kmSUfLzm9YDNWzaO1S4w8mINO2TZVHC4DdgdNO0p1EanfAmJS8HrumQpBO12M9BprrOQM6HSfGfhLOwOq7mOuHeH71ScmGj6i5p5LZR8hB2EfJ4FHWD1wnFAS/Rqjr9gPZ7WADcp@qw1cRWXkrWj8@pVfbvKUVduqPpSqr6kHoWWkNaT8IzljU3Z2US2VLFVOQqbOFKbWzHVFpugzaMC/wCDWLql0cG1BN0cvgFJVEubo63K7G7zeS1MPHIZyp092VqUyNXOYnr50Tc55AY1dCfUW5DKSEDAC24FFsr0fiA3IKomzGjUd8Sf31Sy8e@hwXAb9uBK1HZbJ85HZVrqXyD2TTTmu5SKSKD9yto22I7MHgnoxMVWEoI2h42XnAeW6lR4scUZTXdUOAy0cQmVy8k@1VFLJeFlOzp6rQSKoA@5Unn14aPHa0@ePkOUswXd2vlgUKiAVcDwLCAYrFG7tMjG92o1t5yTTwhBPVsloM8DiwM4mHVdep5x@3zp3auWSxpYKcewLjmMhhTX25UMMoU4CguYEWiN4o5yrvtj5QgNO/7U9r7SP@Jv4x@QGc64ow2E9FY/vE09Uzk9cThQZcHMTnHch/Cg4ukUO2846OzD20QIW1dhe6roNTxAjM9Gg/PTM5s7Ctq11SENGCI4@6XGCuplOE4djFlYQRfVGw4N6/ZF1cA7mm0BjHIxJUDnE@A0zLTfykBbmmJ0LNMkBM@auLGKI0TLdNRmZ@bO/kDVd7enEVu0w9Ax3IJt2UrKHXsygwMZxOq1mntI1NXeLvgqqZZJfsarMgu4EvKV@Tp8gLvSLQSitqhiZDXrDWP3JrKUmRdT16ZpUepH4DUHZrl0OynNvVbTChDECEK9m5QIMT85z7FJluJkdzLGKXg5V7FsRN9EccwO5nRlOU9blHImjiqw4FwDEPs2pZw0pFRBj/JjnQMvS28jmKPcisbWgDZDTlaq4dycHGaCrW5jcYCNqOOGFmh/Y3fLV9t1@rPzYduHorxZ@wntTkI8X49vWeNbrqjGjukC21ss29zCZuo3XFEiZilph7EpghC@HYmKGKZeA@qNHU17GdRHmbF9nHIF2DXQSrjZHdWDBI5eeA9kQS/eE1ccfF2Hv1Vk82pW0iQuVfSwkC2umwe2RZOFtNYEkpDyDiBWp0EkjlpSbl9IGV4s0FnzDvTaxTB2Y2c@T2dYVhZUpLbvFInsWZ69ljI3scWqZovVCvrxJr5gvr2RN07CzkDfRUuY4xbeuPfHeCN/d@bI/3/BHPV/Dnc81NzxsALZI9yRuA3nG50chn0wh2NOJjwHN9vRaYT9oY71ikaUfAsACzxgiDuklFguoW3XiBPlzk9YmZ6PYCS0@hgXA/5Q4x/pxj@qQOby43b4/2rj8//gxj/WjX9cwVwzp@e1ame5W//HtDhVCd3sh7ndC3VXsnl/tKVruqVrFcymc7r5P72l@f@glj7RLX1SgccEOXAQ9/U3c7NoIrWDrUYjNbcoONppl4s49vO50sPaq13N0eKh0z2Pz6rQ1tUfxv@pxv8ppBE/IQwdziIS29BkLS/LU7ksL5ol73IoXLKSlkh7jWd0q716wkrXI3qCEiHNG1sjvVAhhdyXxPS0qZDqj6n0TSafu@Issl0Hy8TBubWAlhVh2UuHuGi@Okjm6loyr2yzD2S1dbj/euW/CBl6wWd9C42QR9deht2umUnsJdhh4nVKN8ZqDmAf6DVHhlU0ORnZsb7tnbDLwvVSjR1bTM2L8xcJctSG8z9aS/Wgb1hRubFlRLQp6PJmVQXTXLO8kC/Udsk0v8m6xX@IS59pLn1WUft6YXAdqQK94ad5MV2nrT5@fNMcIKUK@MEALPmU/4ZR9X8B)

Kamby has `#` comments and `"`/`'` strings without escapes, so it executes shell code.

Kamby code is inside rc/es/xs:

```
`"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`;
```

Identifier [can have quotes](https://github.com/henriquegogo/kamby/blob/8fd947b0/kamby.c#L338) in the name. Kamby doesn't see the opening `"` in the above code
because it is part of `` `"<<rc|\ `` identifier. I use `|` to make error `puts: No such file or directory`
nonfatal in es/xs. Last space is for Pyth, as before.

It actually prints `409 \b\n`, this is [unavoidable](https://github.com/henriquegogo/kamby/blob/8fd947b0/cli.c#L21).

Most of the rest of the polyglot is hidden inside `'` string opened by fish code: `echo 353;exit;'`.
There are two places where `'` gets eaten by identifier:

- Rail's `$'main'`, fixed by `x' '`
- C89: `'??-'&1`  `'??- '&256`

The string is closed in REBOL code (`'disarm`).

Other fixes: `red[ ]`  `red[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## 410. [Generic 2D Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Generic_2D_Brainfuck), 17250 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"F :n^*giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1*_e#8g= ma cep:s561?<p>3sequr=    :
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({6a1ca81e-ab2d-4c6f-a571-b4e6d7f65e41}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKr4xJtvipRUKumWbtdDLaluXV@SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElsaK7Z7fXbXtmPT1tR7vt8W33rGfb64kY78TMuL1jz0TY@3HCMZ/8A8qPjQ3Hhvsf9J6TCYCgREp12/aGY0ECyOfJzJOZJ8/Jx0Fb9wY//WkML3LkWLO@5YzJ2PDGpOua54YrkgczsqObXk7VOA5D7br9ydCwx16ZixGFEEu3@xO9b5CeaY0NN0M8wyBtw3IuwF8lZGtiTzyjWwObRohtXJBDu2N2AQIZO2eGbb41XPDLEvLQsK6GV2PScYZD3e56ZOSa9pj65gg50sHSm3TOiN72xq7eGZuODV55Qp7blj5sd3VCg49cg0UqEADVOaNxln2KhDxxXM@AFJyO4XkOOpbAUXdN5/Hu04@vhVdk8rEOmRpZxvRa8opCXpiG270eQyWfnh4cXHfVyFcFxyYHN7OkZMnuZOwcjq/Dz5HdvmHrRBVLonrdMw/IHBtWUS7K170KUJ/G2OwspQMeB6YLtav7tUg6ug21hXWZIsZwNJ4RgdW/bllh3XpE98jEm@gWDWdPhm3DDQJ6Y90dm3afXJjjARkPTC@MR0N7I71jCF3DMofm2OgSy4RITs@HAqDtLjkzZheOC1Xuw3RsawYRjY7ZMzFKkA8AiFdiPDAYnKE@g0q2x9A4iE48yIZlBNCSXAzCPzTakz5xJuPRZEwgb13T09sWAG3PSNfo6RNrnCFt8AMkU/eLgWH7jRnAiQDi1GG5ej2hWTMWbV7vdokM7RjycWYQE7BGs1UmmgbuxHEBaxAqyJEPjLZrVkZjCnUGVdRzyiQny@C/H7pgbnXLc/zMLGcNPW3oq7TOEO6R6/RdfQjY6BoUp58eHhGv47hggxvDsv50G5iOPiZbWyS@//RhnNTCahHdNhdWUZVcQhXEAk9yrlsTaCHRmnCgftwwNodVFt@Il0kc0KLKJJslWei2RaLmAEmKXAID9H9VU@DOE7VIsgr0oBzR1EI8g2n1XL1vWgaD1EdIBWz8EESFp5wlmlIkWl5jofuO1WNBOzTRAtGKJF8ghRwpwLNESiqkiklkiVLKwZ2HGyCWIEsASNUgg7LKgC36ALRZbHd7pKcPTWvmp0CT6JCcQgoAFfKuAHS1CFDgrWl4a3AXEdryFYU9HgDmB/o5gBcs8wwpkxESJ6xOCV5SKiVR6ojklyXvDTB5QCMgMFckBUg@DxjJQhYAy2oRks/JrCDewLAsP9rAw2g0twUZbsh5AXBRhJqQAacyIrUAN9iB9qlA5FSgaCoQKRUIi6qCWcMkIFwe/PJQrfksS2age2eQEEtH7dIKAOoOYBTEOBI0BZEEEKDWCKAaqjwLjULDRpHTCOQf8lLIE6BpRYUUs6RYIIDPkkygfhTIF7YYBWipAvlREBi0AwUaggJ5UgDbCgBVtBzhIshWNPSHuBrEBdQoWYiTBTNUnJLHG@JB61AgSQXSVNXSokFC3tQclDen0Zaq5qF2C@AHeFMhryo0KRVyqxbBH@MWAYdFbMjQfBkidMQD1Ao2fWiLgIwc5IfChbBgVgt@49Wt0UBvI@VmMds9jJrHLpFHNEJUGYsH7yxiE7IiAxjsDZB9FVqARnsOvLNh8pYCQOoI3uialFhbJtAxJcRQIUMb5Gt9NF6gTcnTHI1m40HopjI3B4ioCYTQ6OudWegJvTATei5c8xq6qpTuLgDJWXT1gMo6E89aAAkNWZUmZZyb1sKtSN26ht7tmd7g3SKvWZpI29DHtnm2SCWXy0SQqkc88uix5FTQomHHpgBDV3@ApkVZ1AKGGTlhBS1lWVFo9tpGb2L3DaFUjOSP@own7hgGmUWaJebsmv0@jM8LOEqGFpMOmgvnHM2hpWljLnRE7GKarglD@X3SGQBzEXqWGPxSaQFDUxHGTG/jCC8ARwYjQgnHsJ45Je37HTqCLDKoUTx1BuYoCFxeGzhSuTSRaTEfaRsUc2@Lckie8WqKrx3TTsRJPMnNORh3GJcZHbVhcHuBIxaOwdh0YYx1KAexIJ8JOxglk4C05QEfRmALyChUSkfH0RjHJoOOrQEccywSSARYQsM5RxaWDpBLyXh0EG27yLECx9M1XJdgWGBzvQwdbr1J2zPeTJCnWuSrB@O3AcN8TzetMAN0HNHHlBmAd9yD9GbL2e65zpAONkMcTi3HGa1hXWDwvkBAj5wLY5H1xdiuj0YWcFDgbjAGDjJzoVPemzLq0VRZhiASxoMKB4A0KeA8TNfoUNz7RYfYGvAoy1ksE7V2X0MoDyKslQadBdgOD@PYE8sqA89jdIhWk7rGuYQujP1aZrswDwFDBmyVD6KtA9@MOae5CCHdV0XK6p0GNes5w@WisfH1MCz6wEQmybrQZ1B7PRhajak@BO6eIAsNPZcMocWwGsSaAPkFi3VIuo4dH4dQLlxgaKHQYUko04w4GZtDAyQhB6JgjWdppnF0pzlrz6ApU2xlRSr6sJxcQ5TIXUcUc8hGHFhnAdavO@kg1jBt06YtCNglD/l9F0glc@PGLmk0dLhd4O1GvrQnogEDnmDWIsKCx3q7z4V3KETkVw3bAxHDE4mJshi0/L7Tg8Z2YULZgWBB1AXsDkUCoiB0moodkaMoxwY0PLOISTqjEQF3GJSgeR7IRWBHndcmeQue1gDEic7EdWdkOoKaMIcQatxxej1ovW@N0QBAkGGXdGYd6J5Qydh6uK5DCUxntFzMhW3TgDA2Cih7Rz9P@gagHZjXHkqq2OQXBRiNaBEoKnSbMba2DpjCInRGM4oWLraI0XMcEd27juHRxuK4Z2HXx8Q8o0@7BvSz3oIYDZFRh1ZqUwGjC5TH714IHxPkVhYGk/JbwceGDV2nA60SOj1UH9bpLumBwB1hYVHm0DsdYzT224lDyZlpR3j/ZwfI@1NXwQcmegNuc4dsXWs1EDRsORFeFmUhzPrIF0l0pLW@VC9QxiMUPxllsWY3kocQ59dS519hmKUcvOLX5GFEuwQKQpRITMZISpA6mp0B0sIxUhvKb0Nvcyc3iw9u0eTdIRF6YdqYGwXIDidKoRPmYz0MAW7rJiBxZCGs2pIDBl1yuAO07g1XQHbCTFrdqKso6SIQxbuADh3bWQEVkBnCxSDLPrQuaGM8QaqhW2FjpN3FW6ojJNiLiSYcyGAMHY0cF3oGIzozOqtAqyzSunxhPBGOFUmRPFgeWmHIiOOAP8ZRECKMLB3aAnYx7KkgWelAKYCIMWEZaJ7DUoxkmPZ6CsvP3wUl/awxwVhq2wYKZ7o7Y0CgeDA8Q0IzYroukMFzHCTYGBQMJiJtpzAm6N0uUlZEB@331xMXsUXvTdrm9LpE3kFH8bXHnesu6aEw7gLTAZ0oEe958WSFutOYES9eckZjiUZlTx4C0kAiVHmiB/I9DBIHQGhOZnYnwS91MT5D@Mm4V@STYMCIjEcjn4CocD13KD5goxmeQb@mtgrpw/AtCPAU0I3mBD0kET10F/gM6IQgZZZK3bZOroB6uESY7jFRJBBJFDEbpmXY3TAtHxGYl2h5RZaE53aoQYiMalgCDE5LTgeJJQR@ICZoRB4cJMkfW9GBcnvMj/I1zHFi0zk5kmCsSJJchswvDAAJmhkTmA@zY45bPrty/37AuGxUq9DYgJsCstlNRiXaYPJSBEoNgUXKjfiJiGPnZIx9I5GE8mLgOcsNsE3QUqs1cjkeuNDjqH3OQSBAK2djSw4Q69fzU/Ns0r1e0TY6YiAeex0wTWZnzFc4GPxZb6jehtX4ElZB6o0jVrHxYnwK@kbjpa5YobwfzDU8ZH@rflYiNZzAHPhtdSWKWFTfbdGg92Ydy2cJmAk6O6NGbcj@mT@pFRKijM8TBJ32Rk9lQLA7MDjkaPf0UdXvi8xTapt2ecnBcjq6RZ03MTgfxH18@OB49/jnWytgWGa7fN1BMrPFPA61k6nQtydSVlTLm1EYC8APW7fDxojLYXjO9yaCM42wSrMODC7TAJ3Pjr96HSXACSE6aApgxvsaS8PCANPFtXVvcG0QJv10GpIMowRhiXBIApihAbOO/nqQn6PJ27dYedczNfLdMWfWRGcAAkfp0A7iieh5jQELvNo9NiLSuMCFmjYuOixM0ZBBfj5Grvl6ZigrHWkyHz872D@uUrD@vJpAg0jeGHgp3e2K0OatCYjgq8IA@QNTh6TFRcaRn6Z5XYngTmcJwYu6JWvgAwCUdUSHCNYwKJo3gLzvXS8bdRU6YQugdgrhOl8Z5Yc6XzajkXzgENdBkXfVKEo9FoNV6LRyxAp9l4etTi5nFLKl6LDVWaTZjQKlCwQwDgR8owteZ56ALuKCi/TZaj/7J49vZNyjTCSIAkKQM88iIk3LsziUXgSTxD1pDyQ0xzLEF5Ti8YRPSlI8WCMQOx4VPiPh96fmOCEn2VtJQlhIfXf3UH0YBPanrOlMBhUaUBbHkcnt4Vpfx4M2YjuW03dICuIw7jBIENimtcXc7Tv2jRrS0RGLGsPlQqC/OHGjj2CsMd9SwZHGioqrbOFRt70LoNJKXkMkUQxRUBINL77Wz3VA16LcJ4ef78MgouRkOTTL9AIUROJQdKGpE3GlDkSAhEQ/PysLGC4d3ujtgYcQWbvDQvuELoy4u/Be6UgppiitDL8yS584NzD@2plda1rgwpoWGCIoO3x69Pjw6f6T3c8aYzWXW7Jn5VIeEAfptYEXEgcMb9hbU6xrYrEQXAz6hovdC6jABASUYOVo4rlAuEUMIrIMrGk1bNE18YkzsONe8nphLtBXeG13WBN6gp2PBfUjgqDdtVAYcdnKNY7n2H4G4/HIK0sS9PLBpC2C0Cq97jiW3pdoPBgYLEtSUHQ5fIbzGt6qGJAZb2awGGxyC1iHGZ1B1K2hA8ILXf9G0kASDDydtbLM/gBkYVwkN9ykGLZgWhqpCxICyMpSWDZKgKkNcOu/g3riWdP@SFGLrF0rspqV@CDYUveHsBs9A0SnBIxWgIrkNStp3G/cJzOg0gjpOpAYEVN0ksMjOBZYBBhJOmuKcn6AHEotcL4UaQXF0ZsJzuYClZJycrag5HMSiGUgpgHPKuCcmzDUx52BMHYEgCc4PTpvEGmFPa@j2z0x5RuCzALfdw@KqtVfNhp2Exj0xn2aN1yDrs@adaWZrJCbUVJ@@GQFWu9S8bDtBg7QdqkRmiZ9kzX0rKvfJGddnfauLpHGw5E/5ggj8mQXGKm3DtDrrhHtexhBinpKqaWwEgZ@J62YELIwKocPxJQEHQpGWmh6EuZLAKYX2UNoOUC3IhHIYjYjZJhm4wHQD40k9qgpeZPDRWfNpxrLWcFJYXE0A5JHAyHRFjTMUOBBExwxCJiVOIhAyPGgf5xlgW03iZAylPux65lO3KPLNMha4YStN4J6pPPdHRwoPJyiHMMAHXY@HCigfeE4QS6MOE7l6x6bMIVI/paDID6IiyEEujAQTorb4SYLaIc0Fp0hAOIFTRtnbgeLiU6cd4DGDgnSPOH8BzAxNl3A6EMhITIryC4rCEuJuiwX6cx2LmyE1jZIUWibY7be4ExcXHo3u9GyQXBNZWEAGi1cZGiha/Rto8MmellkWgqQQ3UyNIYOzmYAg0epkUGLoLP1fRRHPZw0h54tC7hoCfAFsrMHhLRjsCkrYYhyHLTqfRIfu9Ku8LmkC2@hQ93C3mHhI1XsV/ppgIDl3RZ0osafhKUMkjOkgV7QKR/0fBBw3H7TwpbF61VnZNjXxU4mlCaSFborIh5n61CX8Y2NjXg5XotnwLQNpi00baMpDaZtahKoCcOJaKIxMtSEvnUaA92a8Xk9gDxNNrENTJF5eWuOEnq9XNaaGb2u@G8V30moCsA8hBbwBXDiyWoVjckkX7vAZSMQISJl38O2c9JxzZGPgk@AJ2H2aPfi/e7lGhUUj2/HyLDqgtxqIJebcOONutxoNi4b3XRjHs9g7GRFr4KICvRznBiKfdeZjIB3rGfLApDXZF0rNyvtalyOpxKJomBBQnoyea@YTOsM14m4AW0q0WjEAaU@duqdgUvhTTNqMhkiCvLRM0HQsaxEXLwsQvrtZDOZjkPcZDwDI0M1Hge80DVPjxYaJyVYIzowp4BK6JgwykaXNSiNputj2F0/N0aDmRsNEE78AaOPk/iLrTO4wwgHkiihfsviR3nKpcmGgPVm4YC/xvlDZNlGMzbAcCynDWlpo1Yw9J8LvaEz1qVPRZDbxMiIHd@IS4IAgzH1YZBosZ@YHnZh3TaciRed7Fw5B4upg@vpYALEMtgtl4FWZY44ozNwSHxzB6CTcMkJCT@unglsDS4A0O2IcCMRRcYI12uAwaH7m0ygi3RnGJ0YUmgmGOkJlgdy@dEbMUytQuMQGRMy@7bjGgKgBGJwdDMX3SLI1YKl8UM6@XZj@PF96aiKQ5lpAEU8sByd4paR68iS1GgYiW/3Mcqx0eUsoB89II8iqwvX6Eopji4UO@4ARggoDVJiNaytoe8hOd6oK46nEJVL4Jgf9WQCJvC9F6Srqmq@k@uVAz9sFYDsAVQSCsY2SNmBl6CAZ9Kv5H02MxVMEzx99nCfTd/Q8R5HeJzKaw2d7gRYW190OzbsfobsQ3sybWdoAhqC@G/PrGPHGbOJBrCsmxxicrs5nFg6nXa6PjN0a7yO03YsOht1W9RF@Inr6ZbO5sEC391Pn4C48fz0pCqWI4Ek/Xx4a9o4Fbo6WYbPw@iyJ13yDVaoPNYw@c0cj@NWsAkVyYzvkUePib8FFeoocC@ge9ClcBnHdy@i@xC3nwK77k9kUGvo6Acs0YC4JRX33/mOl4o8R/e1YmAYTqHhGO@6yO2lolL383Gvt@SsUeczAUmTtXDOUme2NXVJTI1mKccC4T7VpTBRQHkaJtyuujZcgYZjG2zEcHHzSbgPYmBYwermMXAsuIIHg76FfBXITSglsC2lBjD5I1yooaQbl/9IB/hg7wYXC51tJLDQXGyDdiAY3CRkabhNifjT7xXahWzHXzb1GFl13Ayb2dmqsYV2FOtcJlFKbGFgswUgtmqVYM/fumCYUjweBqNQad4gBi0m3Vtwo6jhThGPzvdzNEqF8ySQaKaqLDSmhf3mVVzyKBp6hG80pvdk9TMQjXDz5uZ9qW9U6DarNfiqBD5xn4dtz4gAHB@GYnPnnQHQGZKeLqMS6mdi9xyrK7CFOmgwhIl4WEH@PolwU6m/d9gw3WA/Kd3Qy6IifY1sRb0B91qV1m4GiGxeDQFB97kkV2eZ8ytShyHvXPRGljlukrk4dloDf7OWfX2bK@NBXVefeZy/zaZKdo8//rQuNxkEbqjj4luR1eI02C0NjDMwSritHUy4WWhsjiknQDdDmFheRYRMTek6DWQfYLAEKiRMyC8RZv3KuFqUpWeAsJwwMOfebJghRnIu9ix9PDZs1ubYCuh6dLOlKj@ZKk1@21/3KBOZLg4BZ2qiH2SxQk5OH@4fH4vQcr1EfB8XkcrQHfXOABiUdYUOMBktfJnc68bJPYyTxJkDDroaSB8tPz406go0epA/IHWkHX3DTYBjEtd/OuBMl9xoRMah@QjCLV@dMcVRCCxhJKFMFFh5Zf6f20zU8vNZhhafppgEdCfulwG3ZlKc2OYb0YOBhvKtEMQXVmG8qG4mKBXbVJL@nr4hrl6DhEWZRihBvU6Et0DlIDBPms0K24YAYVEAc/uIXZ6nVUE31VeVoOqr4AwsDYXgR6@@Iy/rslBqpjdXgaL72/z98Kz8EbgIYRm0Z6xMdjNB@/uNjszywJYjGeV@TsXpa4dBymSTGXg27U2DB3u2KNGhW7yWt2otbwSDToakhM4GYUECkhDzTyv4bZb6U8oPMg9Gow6JJLkMka4iysnVFcUh2VQJxSGYFMIqYx5In0CYHjtQmsf@SYUod0B7q7@XBftsg@MDMWt5sRh9GAsvnV/jToVzPhqPcYemfebQJafQ1JJFJYccYRh7eGbdjIn7YOljKWiYBxZWXZc7b9ju0ceKAHTlxV/Tpw50Tt/nhYGJ1KVj@qLT@ytSXt7HspSsv0OWjrRgJsKbO0IKpSIN3Gu3zXVBAQm4NS14rwgGRArbsypmRSU4@oBTMTAeAeFi0sui6Ne3QJElvPtbef33f/t6F/B/s3YGMFDg5GdoaMHQjTUl9NZWlh8VLfSxumLZHP3EMnWKGGq6C2RHd6FIuhUaVoOm@wAEAYb/Ia5q@DUObRMfwDXe0sxYztmiZPBenciqdT0bSGZnXdhrW8JYUnQFCgS7LkUCY4JMg0aipItVgjFlq0ARERvJ2N2ZCvZtEdqYWb0PJuMJewLjemclmiO8b@ubfkg5p7cVQ2Kb52@pclc/m3QdYXTWD/nU/Iqwi9LTZWgB2AF/RbqFxtXFZwVkm9GD97pgi6FNuqCvu1qFZ0@8kdCmUniX2WhHGN6Sgmux57ogpn@WMDSsx5pp0ccHtkQfOjQUf0OGhNtdhQjSzGtotvT2DHmQwZdvZeHmBqA41U46LWtrVrdHo/XxUZKk8Uul1bGnYofhY9UcgcS21ApsFo0W2N9ke0etwnBlDnVLULsR41pivmpvxI2g4bIqjYPnP@ghkFsbOQ5InYmluwvTLU18kY9gGWHdjLQ/bByZHQfYgRFRCqKiBkNHZMCgJDPYnbdICHc000dkB4a5Co3BiRYhNK0mAU5njLtW17SpDyBobLco7smNNBLRWYepjnOB91r2YQCiKXuuHtHerszVBxAnwepYOozja4eDpclBnHy8o6FemJ5BH6sRe7Yyo@OOtdJ9uQsE037Raby7mrVnWo5HTujzNgT1XcACe65u0FFcmrot0MnwqPkWGhRss1hUqG71HStf7Es6PNbW@sTtId333x9K4UIKpSh3UKiA/XFsxX@vpetnknt2VwXRM5MubrGNGG8ZYleRKX/tZX3pQDDAhbvVJTuQizSmKLGpvjUJ45LLhT4L3j/D0LEOtcHQMZpRdhq4O4xQKoJh7DIW@2dJLXt7at0PI0o3wBbuKkSkcs8sAwYr@rxRpUSVlS8ZQ5HlDydRPWtiTIyVgsaz9msDT/nfImR8eKZkvxib/kw9Lg7g6Zgw1FtfMvygXOM4jbZbiYlumR3jblZmmaiNgPseoeh8BIYjNNyM0bcno6VaXZLO7OPbUTYYBV3a6S7lDn2@LB0q3sEpLfHnnkHvWyUmJuHhHrVqTpZln4GJrLgsWW6TpLQw7muTPZcSpi6LlBdhcZXNjRhXp0HREt0FuZYEqesEexq4VJJs0zbGM3x@IDVtO471ZWoKiCqeWXZAWhXobt/bauwGu@OfYyGLqQsPJzzavXWTFmy08WVLwA8KzbdVenRJ6INqU8BFzyEuSC1bb5@@iSww3ZUKnq/FOSG2/9daz0v6syGKWBQLt/Y6xqE6bcPS2Wuaz94GryRqt8JbJhr@Yi0u7rIl3cVSfOwaURrNAFlmF6SUgTE0qPUWLl/vosYO/7U20NTBe5331DA60nTf6KwLMDKBLtj4XFpDjjBLY8cG@WqMWw1RTrFwM6vvuo4CB6t@K5F8ONT7BlMhcxulXExY4G4aJtYtjKunLspsB00Hoi10g6xvEtCpzoyZF7xXAnwy60C9ToZ3T7dd6/wdnAP9gN6@bhftzSHWHjgDe2AM2Nb10Lauc0B7HDOVP7dlHXLdH@BuutFoaZd9FJ@WY1kfgk8kjYxQOk5vZZ728fwtHh77UnDZYX//defknT5mtAMNa3vNwJjAuOQ5Y2dkCNS2LqiFEz3suY6GBovUP@sM0q1yPmAkeP@s8O@ULfu6Mx6N6Ks1siYefdCoAj02fRff1GNbU@i@TMfti2@dYVv0HUV/3wpdAl9NYtrmuDPAc@usZRt9p90ZmHdl2teVIQVTPsz6QbIrYsYkwkN0Fi0T0OvORGwv1aj/Cb4O11W6P3vEhrXQcAu/smqGjp4MF0b6Wcdjs6FoImWcEI70RnZ@vExP4JffTMzxAmhkL1M4vcuWJdCwLu/@7om1nBU9prEgw/6uirWtlDLpyJALhgwMj7Iu2eV9bpEupmnssS5D0VLSHEX2pXwZdPt7f@jsoBmZtwX3pfa1tGlp5SBnDyZ97ybBZNP1XWDR8LF@2oJup45MWcOYpdv@ax2aVUvCc5bwbgHPNTFuXVPJ3bqoQsMplqA7Jrxa8IKqm6ydQ7PMkceeROitXYrz9zKBLH59vZDhZrZamPYrpmv02BIImu5iEYeOizuRgQcROriSjjPoSMwZ48UIl@30gagLFlkEDsKuY1tWbhNaXf3hmCl89tTo67jX@rE5xs2aK1oFbbKrthfdCftrE90zvzaBkq1rbKg0gi1DulHtAmhbAe@J3jc7j5YqIsykj2B/pyd7LTV/dLpZFxcD08MdTaHhlokpbHKsEWOra4HcsCLk9Xn7UF/GogOxk5grQ6@aW3dGMzywNqOm26bVzTGdZfXf60THdZvAbs3ExWQ4mnj@a3Ue6J6p6Cz08Iy6excmABfeAGklA90ar56pjky5AhfmD4oL4zpu/HPTcvrk86JMgGkDJgyZ8xUN5wEMz0e4Ice1V7REmvYHLnviRIfgsoK9gbo18FyFbY5vn80Zj3FzTvDGwrCRA08oSI/xKe58WQjC6WqMPL6b11@cjr5jfIeWd@JM3I6BxlDlSVQs8FM19oLdx3iiw0GVLRdRKa3jWNC9wGCt7DIdx56MBXdi3zoq5G8dFcqo8CrSDEjia/tPniejrYHu1r6LCw1Uoi1MazcMXGtkpg2M2Ho6uhw6kCUeMlVNx3Sr8B1xdlGfVIeS64fOKnnnaAYDyAcLTED8J8OHRgeXDe9M@6nzxLEdGI1GQCiHxwZTO7C00WN1RIz2GA/WA366dyZzQsGuGYQYt6GPjDbUr7UwfchYxAA/1Mf6mqGIzg1S@S803dlWTKttuK/ppF/EvE6kXc7QI2NKZYv1DYb1QWHc6TCWGOfjlvrI0oqNN3Icmz0ptZXhpTy5narAUEAfH75QLuJG/KV5gZXy2XJRn52zXSJGl@nFWFdW12g7FnvesifJNtmeAN01DU96jGoWqFs@SwTgvrxbaUjhVhqyEI2Akz3XPbpIv1rUWIBUpl9iC9BAdzsOroT5hlt250R0I9xBpsO9/WzjQBsQPwWKpXcmvr7Su7JlDdtD@lgrMERq89ho46mgNlUoMtanNyuTzQz52hQiO7pCHQQBucJOnSeJI5BGkncPW0ty1DJWzRF9UEq9drmcbtYRbNPovNVx1syh@FrMTS/5Q5mlp9S4Zq460o3oLLKk08P2K3vS8tY1YGgsQxgPXJD5pfFt09uBppcV6yGToYGLzMurMGtZV8cb0MI6q9fTQ@LqGoKvbhBoSah6kPGHwu5azhPBw//Zg08kGIRb@Wyg/QRI190r@JD5iWv7rw9pgUeON@6Z02eQbzwFsI6cYLFyEAVerGegKbWuEFB79sRisw/9yL6rYZeKYwJVCi0IFiXXY0Mw7HOB6qKb3iyRww59SbuoQHhsdAVfFQOuNAiPg/NfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnIjHETvNZf/vnKuReBJQB@C1nLIw8@pZG3tHh42en4shTVo5PuwM8HXGDj1vS7aAW5ciU1Gvdjax3su1oXdMbSw9OFGHv8aGIAdbgm61oCPDClbml19p5z0CRrKSvlYLQ1xivZhAfnT55nF4c0SSJvYHrDI1k1Hvv5CSDJ00@OVnpHY19AL2j50zXRj/cV5Tkiub73Karg@uo54qU1kE6NUAahcb4iKmGuZO56jgjo3s6GxmfwuCJFNz7wOTzawv5VD83@9gLSWktomhHJSUxn01GdmaDsG244XtdfZ6ZI6SWHfqS2GvtdhTkHDTJ1VZzD7et@F/nYojs70T4cpEU@WZrjaoylnTv75oxRVHW4flE70G9ktzayloOsGp92HLOP2Ap2fCFFyF0EsbQqgTzzn3kBWEIpFvCB07P@45gbK/dBnMbgNA5v7LDXxj2TLcFupZ1G3tRhti4qe3WIJ8bH7AgFe7wOUd96SvX@MIt9STRocbkHQmfupEoe3sPDu@KcOzj8vZQHz99To50D/Wg3B4wmmPjA3K84IxeCzhvhUr41i6ndl0Apd4Krz9a3Z/L5ER3u449m969CEfPoOLQTvUbh7DQRgMZljk1V41VHTavdbR6m9FdabNDHM5siQ@O6sfxAb3/1r9QFFmm2o/wrcjMekfNBB2cJNCkz1ClXtTr9DAkDR3kW0RwSK6URh8bU9yOwmaDVwn1K8e3/C1jXyG5fji5za94i1/2lvRu@KEj0URZuQVg7hY/khND78eOdTFwxD3dNbwV@49XZui2gpRuKUgpQp19he10YdE3r2fx8eiC/1rZWk@NsZsdDZy2mV1Zht0e6rkkT1Bf@01/fzuF7tLtLX3HP/LB7KvTu5gYKxN6or9d7UEpzdlKLyCCxmBCj0Tc9F5eIG0Dz2vYfZOpeCQPnPE@td0imIUnnlfvRTBHDyej9TkG2ohfxbhOzpcCvgCZ2bnwyAM8Grdg01fI/rg/brX7Op6WhBODqOn00elu0LqenUhqJMVFLj47WnLGw6PjZycRN9eYTtcJvcJ0nQy50meR6tPT7FKyW7WX5yuQtf68EbAbQI/D91o@iBG7T05ukgQU3wbjoRX4fKLbixnTpQrrOmN60nCl59FsSrdRrqzpAdvFtsrP7axwXhLsYUA2TUjbk1otVMfUaq1rlafGZ3TtAdggMmZsCQPqK14yptlBkEMaZW1Hdc4WzM9Sdk9GA9OervQarotDd5EmXnuru8EuObGcC/I41Cq0jjyoq4Hr54a9jjitOqwolLTbuTDtGku1rl7YB1T817oqebCOUbtGM3BDxG3UBOMfd6SDwPKpmrwz/CcnQfC7w@5ZDs7fd83J8O7AFGw6fXdA9xbydx2geXcw/N7I2cBx7buDBs2pXH5gfGAmNj445HDWcT4gD@1e7@5A@55zd6AnE2tsosyyOuhTZ2KhBoFVfvtuf6V7bavWaIhlcZ0nKnT3Bm5yvT/ui3QmHshAZkg8w4jCa3O85Bi0magb6pc3bNF2ktfgfuKQr6Im@RWoePuBdfTJwbpwyws2E1zipyeCF8Z1m3pHM@3OTv7W7FPLh3Q62xzeGnah8u/QdWxmS64bHhfq/1ak9Ei3zDsJWrDhQb1j6wMOaMyfnGt3Uy1gEA7W19mns@lC3FwuvcWUTqzy21MBKf1OJxl8BAm3pitaZNKP7T8zvPXTfnT0/9r@UO94QUNDJ7a9IFhA9tZxAtEZhOUB/eTpg93TF0ePV/p@VR@2V1P64Hsh6sOF2rybAZlKBBhRo1/08DK@QjSmQoQpbvDE4LMriYQNHS@5/I27qBYK1Huf2ES9z5tU4wSEvboiG76WB/DgA70Rvl4LVA9r2hMDFVOwL1@Nq5uQTLWq5EpkGz8qVyaKTNPEb2aWmBbOILE62bz0dTaUy8qcbFQJX@aJrzUjVKrPFMMDYFRpDYUiwplCNsfgsxlofCD0G0fkitCJaqGDmoPBJkpR3TcVXycG5Gnz8ujwaP/kdPf0@Uldbs59nRlBKWwbUgs089zTujwU3scbCMDsMxFUV4sFydHvL@EEtxeUi@A33ZaLVl0q2qJQ/DbG2by0bUmiakMkYQ75E3iWGvVFNg6cGOygxLSCfI0xZabBgyoigTpioHmaJlRamcirEh7pIMxt2r7/9U8gUl/8XGYZP5iJCfua/aEl9h2n66foGeTuK0jxYPfw8fPjfRJkcNFqLszueFAt5diHH5gqI6innkn3UVdJ3I8Sh7qqVuMHcUBMXIyTMlX0Qj@6AA0dggXYQRUxfuwUSWxS@IDBeFgp0n/7ujSPi3gkKAlh40Gm4pAstHnaUDY2NsgpNBLy8Pjw0/1jgvnff0idEUUIgpyilok//VGXfbYo0AIXfCrUHVLJi2rR4qKaZgL1KwsNMYhz2ndH6z8YSj8TRPWwhN8nCj@wxnH081XQbi@oDtlryj2TVN8e@8Cpr3s1SIg2oeBTJ7j6jHpUkaabnolaYDAPPVRrutzYccMq1SYskl38Gip@c1Wn39CCrE/sMVMd6CsQi0FLE0OakyGbNLPsi1t8JGB8awMae9sAoZx4tglswbhMXkNLxBXeMtMSJAi1@I0oAegyNQkoyEUC3tCD6kkNV3r/K/9M6lcImMdg/rZvnsoPwPZLvq0H5l9m5pcSNrSbelMXeYlmCNUt@yVgGQnxj7iPfATWZpqZFohD9a4BYSXmEKrpnGIdg7MU2FMAeryAk6h/CpUGzQ1qzNfIxNIz3GYC9T2XJQmbFE4UiZS7MaZsc/o1vc/5XD6rSJBJ4TwASD/U0ketGwxgMlmGbsKdm6PqqzY0ta0twuNssVHNV1jNSpv2S41/FWZ0E8JywE1A5uoE4kCURQzwq/nRYPRJK0mMitQrrsSRcHUdGJaoPw5faLd9RPAkAchiODLwyx9T/F7wGGQoX395G7@wG/mI16YPSFBgTKKmJM/5uoyeOmNoPtBJF5/pY7qM8HAGGwJRK6/HvqJN1YZjexRv9qyFCo7ga2F@XxORBjBQmnx9NI3WLf8CQZwgiDK/qvnWX5LGuGE3JdY2CTTTH6xozDaYf1Hqr2mzrNy7NzU2J67rW0ZkkZ0T28Fp8QMoDEmokqpJSj65KFI2u7JIfon8ZKA4qBbuCpIDMgUko2OYr52Rt7u3f/jJs6OTG1qJacj49WBA92tb6YYgZurN0BCPFmu5Sh4cSCdPHhwEFbHIdD5CjYHw@yVRbivJYrULQS5OT14v2qocXi/d@hy/YPpVrudXU2/LGo10Ix@K/CXSpUyncEDPIV9PXC2uwlYud1uWFvCkCOg9pkTiRlYTyct5vQkyqR2L32wJKzrCy5iYwk4ApoaX2pSwsd8sHBYs/L79KX4t1Iv2RW11X@Q3NVR6iTpsxs7ZQi2o7xDxiJQ3SAZIJCdKQdC1ve8ZY9IXymtVoP@YPzoyRHUBRjKcl2/DeAQULSrwOC5SkYXqbV/r9ADkRctsc4EORqZ9OlCSGyqeZvoTE0nO/4YUSzjBDgaRaXkq0u3KiSRSOworQ25TZB3AS3LQoZG7O5qA3HrkjNg3Rei2tIdGYDp2gPw@nLBpbIN8MhlCuB59HRt0iwBQbgEiAybjYVYZLwVUwtdjPU2jpnBIr47arP2Ci8NuLjFNigNj2jX7QNsTyQxQtHuK0iShrmssNNVtbcd5WmeLWri1K36MqkGiaP9SCs@niwzodV007a4xTcQv4slyE9JH9/jFi/N4kl/VlqjidV8Tefe6BvYw@wXldkqij/3eGag3X0UtSqWbVALcrgNmmkCDDxqWSuLA4@gHaqvIuZ@M3cdgBDYi0RvqI5KY2EyLqkioNdFI2BmqXlKoMQ3NNkmnqUAFL@ohEhqzR01s/E7o9owkpCp@wxhcPbuLr7fmiNQVUWyCmSaSJJv4odE94LhQr3CSAyEYopQp2Co2IRAzIEesk4isgUMc9Iew8KK6aFd40@8u0pVUB3FCS01q90nkw7HLnCNfKpX9Cl2miiUCre8mORQlAHuDzgV8PWDXV7AGOAPxV@RiC0J@k@LFaLoxlpFHvmY2yE4solU9UNhGANZC53ln4OKd2LehrwB/UC4/Pz1oFZMST0INb33X7OJKP/s2SSji@V@Tg24qLQWNV5hE9zFGQ126LaZCDlW6HtAOw18jqbEoGnx95IGw7C3apqLc2ur9iH4tQMgsDgD@SfhWAA71HwczZiv8VhP7n/40hsxGYlNRzlrueTqekyvwUCo5kiP3NhuCsFmXqzubOkhR4zfTBsjkUip7bjwc9LqHfanB80QjWUlKXV5exg9SR@bLHMkLXVPNv5nO5lpeezOda0rxzdlIydfFN9MmX6xmzpqNepMcHX32rvUuyU/PZ2940kiArLn3jFeyfKxcIpfbeS12VsIvrIN4c0bewnXWI/in5rfdiFlHc7sHImycJ7FGAzCu8AVekurxJvypuP8KLib412tiTdxuvnuXrOv6eDojpmmOvG4XbmcAHKSaPCEgL98HSs8iSKRB31SCgis3nAKx2zX6/cm@PjMnB@MdsSAWRTUyu7D15PMX/lV58fw5Ic/J8@dvj9fMRTTT6YQg1Kl5es2v3NJzMfxG@p/@eGOeuTxqbf3pN4aSsYGvZ/j69vwJmk@U3L2NjXsPHmSzGVVVmfno86Of393dzT7M5I7que2sIG9s/ckfb2yo6pYqbTQ9T2nG62dnn/GqnOXFP/1hvHV09DXPq2n/59ff1RR8FOBxTgpAJ@DSiAJGfBbhVpDH@tAr9jYGrVyJzeivFQvcLzeIUtsu/PfvPnsTG8dqqvTChfc49iaWL8aYEQxg0wLbeawW28Jg@XlsJlWrVTAW/vu/g/i1TwAO@sy24FHLBbDys1hNqNIoV7FaHgyKqkK6//fXvx7JISMTVcrGBdcOqcPFZwsqv92EK0WvLQ415wqyJAXh7PFgbDhEKd5X7qPFBAu8bAM/QWKMGzGlmCXPdiDkcT2dTjfFlgCX@JJOEkmKojYU5T6QA@FeqloVUoTpBta03H38vkGSTmn1HRgxjfsvlq7Yi7@XayWYyt8D4GMult/YefWwVoPSaTUtVUvTy@9StHcVirzj7PAkQ17FQRipN1@RymP0qvFyUeUzmcxOi3WNKWJNmAZdJIYXe8ZioQt2XnLNrYb9vklCdxaL3IxLoqBXhovt4/Vn/@HPvvdn36W/79H7P6OSYbtr9qQUBDqHzlGDa6dc7tRqfM3lLxtor0GLksvFclFqzRuJVL3WPCaK/PFVPKfFTwiOAwqm0Ug26jR@jSZb85NHey22cK4xl1rUzfdggakDvH1Mkdgy1qg5xBoh18LBIOsfxxDq57WmgKxRVagr@VxTYLHqO1A5vFoo8a1mTNicAd1RmzU1pz4jOzV2kcGmRxzMjabmg4L4@a0tyrbwWdhqUadYLYhWW4T5suH8PJW4WL0uNQ06MtSCjO5slDeK5XxZlVq19VdlEQMvGtQwjCMvdh4Lrwrx22GAz1jYMiNuL6M1EVYLCRowWYp7RzioKyAR0DPYf81Fq0vLK3zFN6ktnlSgfaiaoPZbvKzwYWejE/1wbcCP/uEKrfjcoC6@Mw1y89ogZSWlalLuXn5fxYH2@uUK9Vp6i3brZi0tIlEUxGthOBg5SKfdbr/ttIEP0fW23tGVsT7Rp/pMH7cn7Wl73Jl0COs8ZIEGV3NyTtEJrKIQ03LKZuw@lk1TS2oRP1SpFYtaSdUKilbIawVZLea0YkkrZLVCAQBqBVUrlbKqquULWr6o5fNavgTuKoTJQxgNIRRyWknjYu/qG@SY0bcmSQdXI33n9VwUW76RGhy8BcGZxrjYP8BVU1SFpGAMlOEBjB81glyOP0XhSAyYucvmu1T9XYpE60fwcwkvsbXTTAvzeR3MlYr/36qFxgq9mAkK15yn01sva8DjvKzV0wDypQ9SFAgFKrZqpLlFvcLU/OR8/60msElCequ@VXX26C3Szic0AeTWUjZ3dmhL2oGYtU3o5Ml0elMQNnDkrfvjDwTG9uaXByA1EySedeJ5Z4dA4X/GG6RJICTzrXltXt@az7e24L9Fn3P/Da7zrRt/@lpca8Is/JtIhBp1qdaQGj4haoJdlGroIkoNMNTgDeHqmlps4tCHjIzY/Mf5FzOLZ@iCWW6KkGsuliKpGGrT1WIpLvbq/Rf/G96N91/8HjKlBH5GmYtdEsLFpBSKtCUm2cKD2E9s8oRdNpjxDqzogg61J@hos4eNq16S9EokZbawkFCK@aSIY3vL6bVQQY9IXkHQG4SV8Goxz7fSykwlsS0@X6C09OduXPF4/J@8UkuFOJsNQg0zrzzPexLJ5SKfELiiyoqgXNXYR1TY965@btX1T35u3cXFrkrEKAN@EoQhhotBO4pJkiDUuFhta4hHkHA9RkDR97z6mfB8V8C5Gn1MV9s6bB6ierhfLZVqKAgZm0e076QepuCpwH9/A0pBGj0I2uhVO0Ngshs9Lac28IMbMaH9Bn@P3@KPnHbwd/wGf@T0Lf6Ox/gjT9r4O32Dv902/k6H@HvwBn9P3uLveR9/ja9omlLhNy8pYtJKSZlvTnmKoAoMXbXGV8burEy/Hser2ypIrv5sVkLLlpKxxleMaccYjcv@tCOeBzM644peLVXaVdUP6m9mRx/R9PBkAK5H@bOMZZUkcT5UK@UcV8Cdl/AAh7RWUhw3/pPvfOMb8Wo1LsTph7@y4Ca0MVCbBgIrxMyynOAHlSF/UN2eF6/sxL9SpzMNuVKzjp5N8OBiVbKpbCqyJXdkpa20wWAS2SXyQB4oXYVKZLJB5Jk8I/LQUbpgMuAng8mUe0TuE9mWbQgGvmAat@Qxmnrw6sOvB4Bc@Jm4qb@tyB0CCVnIk9JvHCstjClftRpcncQJ/8oAkVpURFnMm038LFudf/WqIaWaaqlIRGzWYqv@qhFv8g0eP9WhlrKkPTM2Gq944DxknjV/dCExzwM5vRKTGg2JIR7QRWtyPm@19p8@bLUkHAkbxKild9JA4Hd2qkDw/dd2rFbZbpTpeBGMGTFpa7tR0wQ059MwGqjolv6S1wIivGsbtOTNVxevQLJJXKB8c3EOr4vA8KIBjxaTfKi3dPGiEbFSgyRdXLDQKyAsGRaMTPQPguE/1N/8x/V/8pwkSaLeTCYu51sJeiXxl0xezi/n/rOWTCR8S2ILfugAdoxyOa@hkQa6BFM9kWwm53PmBs9EcosBrEEyWzUadxEOxpNYmCRNlj0Sf79vSNq/GvEKecVvbbmdq0aFdv@sXCIx/lWF6IudP43GVJaTQKL8DwjhOrZ@RbdXJCv067Gb7brS/JMf0o9EbSdpoFy2UlFShFnUrFqpZANboVipFAPLZiJRunnV5G0lD4JRNptMVipg2Q7AymCFuHXyLk2qpAHP5v37LJGienUVwNSy@bSMO64qlSClHCRreHqH0WtgOQ@f0Q8sAZnIxQhSA@JvPUnI9AttSMfjfJm/fz/RNfDgR3d7N3n/vlqSr65Cl9EInJQlp1ara7qtFrprV1d8i6e7dUo5sMvFqytFLqWVOEk6buIpfj8W0koICrmn1miyJSDSarYA3n4Ocltb@Wytls@CS74IEaFQjERXSJyPV/jYJS2GUiwwAsZX0JnEoEPD@OhdzmO0Jkk2l0wA8UsC5ziP4c9FOsnGp1wuWcnKcuxyzrPASqnEQidJNp8opkv@r7qRJDXgjtgPWTwtnU0VUjvALOPPm666kJRWLo2qMq9eGmWc859XYIT3HOBtUD@Rcf@@VgLUFOVKg/PpbxVGIGSw4NHg4vE0uXefQ6VNbrxc2aE1qhRzJBavMEchDnScFAG3kprKKUXEBWf2UNsYMAkcE9Q2yAan0jc@uBLjpTbQEQSfG5SP68JFuqRN@niRPgqUxCQWvYhFmD99djphIIddvm9opXHxCl2M8GLz7FpOY60Tht6jx7t7@6cZdUsgMfVgdy@jnjx/EFPQmlvYqbeG9uP93YfPnkOEo8f7uyf7Hx9@uv/8CNw9crG4wmEhGBzCQSJiWmG/IC@41@5b3TB0Y2IYrYvJ5OINeW2aLRPq0ppAoZy@SzyjBWUZ6YtyVeDumJ7@@rXujuhF3v/gW@9/8D@8/@3vvP/tb73/7e/95IvvfQvuH8H9Hfb@zr8t5fD5ky/@xe@8/63fBsf/DPcfwv3jn3zx619nN7X/Edz/NeL2R/4dCcduDmD90k@@@O4Pf/LFL38f7n/l39@/ef/Kj1ff3/vm@hvjffd3bg/znX8H9@8yWEHY7/wWc8P3jfC/xcL98vff/9q/Z/8/8X9o/O33v/ZH@PAt//z7f/Jf33/jP6pq8U/@zftvfvf9N7/x/pvffv/Nf6q@//V/o8jRx@@8/97v/@Uf/O5f/sH/TP8/os/f/ZD/@@//8z//3//8P/35H/j3j@H@92D68Z//R@inf/P7P8D/d3//b/7wB/j/X//13/z@r/7NL/0v1PAbzPD//Kt/y55/9Sv/5a9/89t/@eOv//Wv/vivf@P3//L/@OX/69f/y1/9j7/3V//sG@j4Gz/@yz/8pb/4xrf@4pv/8i@@8cWa57dufX7xAe5f/AO4fHg@PwTOh5Try7p88TPl5@@CjUUq0E6gdf/i@1//BWjgv0bI@2/9CA/2wr3m/yNVoWF@xGz/PzCoN8uMPjKY4P7V99/6DqLofwIUwT/E17dDy5IPs3x7YQG0/uaKSL/4ky/@5Q@pLWaUa3RJCYfuolpMp0C8SZVK/vDtrzZBlF9YhhYC8FP6NlKoJb9vI217/4Ovv//hP33/g994/4NfwsFbyJYyuxlBuWOpDgLmPiAcBsx/SDgM@Bmk30rTGToh/RnYNj7LFTXbtiufffYZ17qS8AT5zhX5DH7ks@AizAtPmPtegR@645FzAu71V6@auL4bcZMUBlxS2dv3wu33kJKg3ktvS4rKvIwraZPFIhVw0IpaI5J1qddLleFH4FEupy4zwnYDOD8adc4ZQZEUH@qGRBQ9o6U0HQJKWRaOlO0dOZsupHQd5Ng0wk1THigVcGQ5jUzTfpJTfw0Y3SHQNEWNU8Im9qfUe8pN6VIx/AuEFIlGiM3@FY6kKbtEL/zSbmCkBj9esMxMjVwOkkkvlg0oi0gYl5ZiLnTxnKabBZEkjWHSU5C9wQAppMHrAUgA1WoaI1ZZFsHKClMrEpqVdLoK5cbYLE6mVUQQ0wcUCsSspo9JK1WdsohphFcL0JHm0OmYV1Q@Xaw@hASr04cEYSFwCvbVq2qtWJ3WENw7hp30NP2A5gmBVdPT2juwVylMiMfFHr6DrBSr6XStiAliIVn1ZFqsknK0cLTsaZL26wDeeAZie4eQe7xS5NmKyQYijIXGZ3oRGgNCcPBvpFN@ceg/MNI7RRG@QZPyUyHMf5vyyNuMbcYAAFcQRFEkcOOmhG2yA95TBipNk4VXmkFI0xZBW0DoQHA2Kc2laf2mqQXSB@cL1xwbRFWzFRA3KgSd3A6H3yim29xlbnOKeywvic8iyxVCpyTnnA5hsrLGXV7p/lGFTZ3MwSnPYQiWZupLX5hZRNbm5iYXq/Ea/0ykVSNJxD0r0wMnuAcTBacy4fMlHp0NevomKCvEr2D5yPuv/zCWlQsxbjOOi5lxwlIg99Ls3tlJkXuAT/qOuE3pgQ4hrTlZJ8ZgbqXTvAqp1Zw09zKFuIulKbQrTpxW6QpqmstkCBGrMfQjz54987NEHV5WuTR0KlVT0I4LeZPJJAYxRDEjZjL@W6Rv6iD6BpH6@m9xE9FKosKbAgI9Or579w4qnO5nKx@CGE38rW1qtkg9wYHpBrOsWXBCS82WODbPQJR8lpAErVq4kgSPIiWgjSY5dg6CtZPgSsTVIgjDGBJQLyZSwV7HvILEhZ35okfFSa6wZIXcRK04bcjmpnHNPjxsxfKXKOaSgefeM7L37MmT/aeno2aTcPih4MnYaI1cp2N4XgL9dp8@ZO1QLeWTsXodsXJaVpHYcftlGdtj@vDh8eFJmTAs@RWUoOWo0OVuHy8lhYuNRi@2Yv7WMB6/9urwJ/gsL1CRUEtAiJOxGhfrGChdQbvDP9wV7onXf@BMSULO8HxGyaO0m8RlW8jHzzsTgrrImeIy6N94kEbc2qIY4GqXQmRxCB1q5FjlmEFQqIFopWJgKDCDUshjALb9kmhc7WT/FECfPiOKKotc7TMyFTFrwpyrWVXLsPvjwSbuY@QbMh8p/WZdzuBP1TR4Ktl8RskVmhsb1qWACTVoe7jEDalzsF4KWOCP4CLcRxz5CJzgEuaEw22mxJ9sP3xW8TdaooLQBNttySs56L1JDhcMfHjcKHoBOYpdW3HjYhuffz4mtdr@04fC4QHOGkwHJNhtKJhdcSDSNtGduAb17RPSNT818Zu/Ytf0RpY@g14ICInN5/MeQDo8IGpNpVYWo4vPeYe6tME8n@ocUM4eF7sfzI5whfvlcvWdki1Ahsrld5qqcuDApSTc3rgBrYfuDUlJ7FfxIFFNK0opLqbwPLw0TeNo2ydc2eAI3Qr0Tq5WBZ/OZhW6E4jD70rp06oaXn7Y6b1FWE1mYdEHPEh/7BI58CswP98WkGbINe5@xJ3sXMUnBvL9@xpOA2lZOSwmoUggc6iwTS2rYSWAG7g2Y9mCv0TF83wzxlnGmHSrYI414FFh/VCJ8QRtSKe0oszF6jHolVy9Wa/@f/9r1rnm9B/vH9BSr1e5KRC36O07Yxj6Jks/jnviPFv8nz0bRq23/ofPnCfPnKEDfxiqniDlqSz@lcqS9fa/T/SQuFRgLOLGeAJKhl9WznH/6C/o2bRJs8XRLV@FeY3u4a0rpWxzH7pMnTS3Au3mNQi9xQ5mE1QrV@WxwNLY9A9r1zzD6ol4@K/Kb41qmqzyW/53VGpBxFq32nU6E9xtVemKpm0bLh4DZxGyWb7i2KiRuBqsQMJYk7zk@tULqqqGM6p9EZXcubZucV2x7XRnojeeWXiMznLcahxEn3jgsYBuAE@M07/bmpYtQ5HEkTPa5tRcIV1XZGAv8FaKGTWzYWwXCuWu2LEM3d3OlXPFTBdP6Pnrw9s5udwXP3vy@NF4PDo26LG97WwJIqBaWFTguF0s53LQYnk@XafJNOtyU2SDjrCxAWTa0LsCvHH52BPUYhMid023Wo3HtzVFFZSyJhfn3AJxgPOBUsvK2S0J3iCnSbgsDQMi4BSRrGxJI6w@MEIQHYxtMOa2pDYYTTCWtiQTjJOapshb0oTVIuKsxmFm0oirDNZkZqBc@iNF2XZsY86VM3rGvKSoLfd6vXnqMr2wcPqlwGyA9LmgZ9qXobUiRMKVySQjmAtPcNF7UIeX/mp7mVdzRb5SryzshTxfac65naHRNXU8AtiQL2/GysP4zaDGIKEG4eZl13HG5bbRc1xjEVBT8kFAlqGbAbL8PEyuIWOKlzeTy0cCTS9vQsnm@HkYK8gWN59DZTJ8Q297@ZKLpY4/1Wo1aBiX2YKazWVzqpbP5woq8BylbD5XhEqV83JOVaEXZkvFUmEOvUCS3sXox3/J3mXQO8r080cJvcz0d9ebJPnuqWldFjWB9eNEsgLDWOwdF7t3/Klaq62fukgAj/apKtSqWq4EJg1NqkYHPVUVVE3QFEHR8H@HQcX/h4dX4a/iE2JpKneKWv2eAusEnKFNHqN2sLFDTh38PmSfPDA6a0LsDXR6QmHPdTzv7xDmgW6fMa@HJlOlH3o90vEjud7QHA/WhHg@GqJCQMP9B4OwP2xDBpF6sgAP4OFajrMqQIE8P1pTyifhx2sAGezrNRD8@PDjR6eR9@n@7t4jLk8ePHv68Nor5wfKkcf7B6ehtcB8g6i5EMTP7z9@fN3qv7LPnh/3Jo6LN3fw7Hl28Qid8AA8l4VrOVDoTIH4D7RSOQRYSLIBYlhgUDg8NnU/WyL3fWMuvzDKaHzBTvebXniMhyl6KHOnwZF/naomaRukw/Q@4kQT1cnsS4pKocRxI2I7F6Qgk65jWbpLnF5vAxwHOh5fNlD@sSxsiZj0heNa3Quza2wATwNplECM7NFMcI8AyHDSoSqFgHtFDf8wCNoE12/b1sQgkxFZ6wgvdEKja/YHMGRfOEEArq3rBO4ve0F8I3qNb3cYszSo2w0f62ZwLsaVYjy/x/OP9LFecY3CyyMXhm2vb9T2p9BUoePo7ixTzGj8OMcfkLL9MtXHNUDLGaGk6o3qqQmw5RsbIG7/1W/@6G//@Fe31Ya8J@Ps5ZPHWXUGrIUiVdrVdyD4D9tXtZdkO@vsEIJsPEp9qZYRK/arICgTkGzLXi6vbOMw68Fg71bpORWgiCgUERR6CJVrfNlHpCK0WirmiiVNLWaKpWI2p@RzuYyiZpRCsVCCBGSlqOSLuZKSKWZLwPFkS@CbA1mWSU5SICpJqTKAtTvWpGtsUSlcHIC4zVb7yduEniQxPbRPCG9AHJ7DGZIx1SORMqswrhJFJlqBAEQoEIkdHOzJBwc8/wAtuNlpT@b5LlpyRVkuPOB5g/rsFZF74x0Wp4hKl/kxs8jyA6igCQOA3yvi@QFa9vM4fc3zJlr2dg8OMJ0eWlSMD8HOmA@zWIGlAMFstIA8RwG8CaFBsF2WTpZmdB8tmCT6HDCfPfDj@Y@D7KDPMQvGADwKSrq7y/OHzLK7iz57tNg5ltGvomWXXjzvggX6Dc/3wdB3ocfyfBuM2Ht4vgOmzkwHtyGY8JM29ljn@RlDDyKI56c0tN454/lW4I7JfOrnJofYLVOLwkq9Qy0l/PG8GmQag2mhReP5bGjJQtkePfpUH4y7Rp9dM5e9O1DSR4803ZxO9g/aH3/c7vfb7mx3/@Nj9NrbewRMymzitvttP2K7BZcDsfYeqfrZcHb9glIftlpl3Vrp9dVWK6vb17xas5aBOYRYbyBn/tXHhIatPfDae9Ta0Vft2qAAW0g4hvBu4/VgCO8Hept5BRf1ou9pu81XsPlLUiPBoWyCGzCwO54BIbYzQ73jOhW0T6tEzmA3ntXzcrNCPcgQZAy5Mkf/XgKfOs5CJi9n9WlVblan1YK/TbKX4BtTNWfymY3htlLKlTf0bUXNpqdlVGXj9OIkLijbJKHcT70liafJbRXkjQ2@sb0t8HWluZ0vvET6VMbHtqoUy1lZJUlm1QpliCPHZULwkawXmtuFXHkRuVBI65JaLhSApwP8jIEzaONUYIskEheGfpZMYtbpdBOUhxaczGihzUovMc1MqyyTZJasTKtKhX3XgcjXoCUSXfyI0KSDuuMJA9oHgNNtuYw7fhK8UirykAdJSiSBCM3nc4acyywILpeX3uVlYx6SRglMizm9F187PTs9/YxylTV/iuzINZDGVXzrx4/2xMNngQ2/CyQeILfruOIe0rYlH8b2Bk6nIMOIj2CcBgkzcMODxa5jift0DyywzIFHoJpQ9HX0i6ePluCcDJwLljLqZalQRc92xyD42SSzS/RqDUx6lyRoroievKAcQqtWq7aqQ6q6BIoYxPoqod8UWoA59FjeQ20xNPolHrb1PVpVeQ4D1TQ2BTitKhGUV0On@0pNdypd/FrSg@oDjFxpwbtdMaqG6zouD@IhX@lt29WJ7ek948hwUQ/S4bNN4FfwBG6iR4zkJmnsY@g9FHPmQs0l9iJnTyfDhC7U2sllJ5wpDh0QOYmvBYW@pIfCW1Wen1d6VZJ4CUHfgN3dJImu@CC5na0Anh6QVhKc5Fe9Vz2ikny2QqWZBMKCDkfxg@XWk9XaV4HNYqDPSLkMufEr@gygYmIAGOqA@ujJkTmvdKoWSQhkmqQ4ylb61TpGv8LHlgAcgSDUr5pcTRBecDXo1JVZTK96kzb9zh6R24oq5ytTcFMK2coAald/Oa241dHENSoWWP1ZY3b8Xa8ATgF1AObtVeL9L3w9uSXkqsytQkFdITvRElvVacVGzd3QLqpaFTzS9aycyRWB08gVMsAYqPmMks9omWxGKKArcAWZXAYcQYoCLiZhJXhC@Iw8lUUloxhKJiG/MruvkpmzhAzlp0hLZsbOvj0ZEnSBqsK2Se3w1pNpNQWo6TpE3xJoUwVSUsFyAc4HZGRmBhTSsaFbLEJSIFoqYW0mMNDm6WS0X2@Wy/vT0dfAKyG82c6nC3L6bTJZSWwkq8AXcbUKV0OyQ0s92oCG60@oE28yrEMlg0kpqOV6vY1FLMgZTdagdGbrqr/F1/hmRt7IK1BFczofpRBGNqITysgWLdxGLeTuLQOqTimpFU6kk7taURVKUi6Vk9kMM4vJjXyyh5gkiQYfqHpIxOMFNR5fSMDJeAWX0zb4xbIIlYvpPsdEHMgwid9Xc/ltHpg4vsyXVB6CLagoPeAvBxkGNm7OIUdKsiBPX3Lzy/lWjSNf4U7w3PaW@hJ/hZdPdp/h7yvgVAJr8eWT58@ePzvgiES3ZIutWGWjIlZaFbAIYm2Hi5UJAeLa8HXTSRuEfNnN3umt2kv2buApIYDL0S901EmTbsI0TJQWyaeo92SbxKEQujusq6rWrKsFGDSBwNZlFlRVlQrkohWjJ9pqUEHTS8jfVrqGR4a/SmYzPS0ECL5frvXTm7I6i523@HxJYydea4p8Rjbi91ME@CCBxM7PNmpqKh0/Kmvp@MO4lo2dJxqbtbQyi0sklVZnPdw9grsQpDiEU43UPS0Vf54uF/uZspLGpwrPcpwIG7GdVmYnWfI4Wickdm3OY7e62z/erQS2vVpRnflHnWMvW3yx4GexsQkoU9Mvl2PXYKR@iQs1uE80XonHLuMkFp/H5/V4k4vt0APVKjtQTWLhkWrcv@EvPWrZPEnGSknfVijFvES47veV@E4sjstrZc97F6OtKjil@tVXKrTxmO0EDiBG4vwdjMy5HC4sxaRXI@9ztag9OXxmP3QPDC7W2LjacHBFMJixhuud/cnXCBkBiuOkUY1Nq1n/MIhSqwnKlooqJAukDKNMT8kL8lWNdaQa9cir4PP@F76fnW4Vwa7KCthVNZdWazUlBVxNbPT@i99DZWCX@5/uPiZxXAr62z/@oVr42z/@13S7aXxOl4dUrRCDkGhU8oXY5eXo8hJ4ijnzy8WasRu7bJqAH0nRS4WUCKWRijoYWlKM4RG4r4KSjHlCzN9knM8JiYQiqcmUVpST4HPlK/tLqHIRrMHyKnXi8zk@Gds/NnOqsrO1DSXb1rJqZQPqUgkPx5Pwt2V4Jaic4pNXV4SApVPr9vumSk2SRMrvhK13RNgi73Bl852wQV5Va7hLSMEj9cFiXgqP6uLaeLyWllJxAlIbqdXnlXkzTZcDqXD8MmU3ruGhsYHHv5adUjb8jJRHf4ZBrdTBA2tgM1KvPT6RSkpSt0upHa62CkItxnpIyyC5GjSVlAS5TAVreewnCI3k@1/4dVXN/@0f/8pV66r1mQoSb6mUV9TYT3@6NbEnntGt/RQi3qL6KZBaKYlFHU1oCKVdwnTHmn6s0CB2QNCe2MjZs/CB7IvSLgF@x@zbRpfKvtw58mi0RltM@2g3QYOlUDNMhkoGVNtfssJxAdfMOH@338lQGCSFqu7rzSR3yX2EXsADEJAeKtxHC1AEZwosy@m0PGvijuixuQSNpzQz5D5EgRQ@Qs2uG1SjjT9aCEA1pdTNqCzLHsUa5efI0PA81BMLYx/3EUTxvwdizchIR@VLGNK0YYQSMQjNJ/Xo1iHtJqRtsQgt6pqgpWcBMoTljkWyQSDgPgIehmLBBNaGmFsQoALk5CNAAJQh4QM2m2SLaElyaabTlYUS2jmBSsdjZHqg@IXDaAiti4qGgsgVDAdOIIjgF@ixXfg1DIxlxDEAwmCw/S9VEGUwOrUhs0g1M30wKIBFtSAmaNHI/fuLXFWrZjdJaIkQ/pk5wik9Wg/26rwCsEAmvNct8xmC6n0rgWvY7ADjaZpdaHUC0@tbiUQlPFrnHAf/D2602CKvVRX1qGAB/PpivaIDKIPIiHZWhx2yVSWKWkiSMPMdyHuHZoqq3wgF3cb0nqh@FnjOIYc/jQXfdwRidRqdJvXb7XXNPwQY/Al@XA/1PzJi4GvsYRoekegdjoPYYSwoimnR0D3TBeGK7s4JlMsmNCWJ0RbKeGk@6AkaNUvwHEsuiS8aC0MTeOuoJNVPZ4Mqd@s4UKHeyLGpVlWq9Q1PEkGLABrlK6Rk2Z7YF/gxVr9uaORojjyqjBJbPuaYaol1UH0WjYu7XdouSOcBbjLE6IukM@wStUQStKFRxZl2CC5JI9EMt4FLRxy3LWMIWToxDHp41StLUh@YtEmbag99YkK7GhyYMPLYnvSQIVi6MM9M6RS/iiA4PTzjynQxxZCvw@7Htsv4mjotxzkjlnlmsNnvxJImK4@AmAKcdgYwu7gBsWXcz6VqGZxSUTIsFNwFeBWYsZiJxN1IzJI335qykWhhjV7REcyEWrGMc92O4JdeV5wvnnszL9CFRzW6gV0MSa7ha8GqxlG/TajejfO1@lWpQjkRV1VGCT7GB9rw0MiNXOOcoKDN4RgDRLMT6JXCXgyl/YgOALTvQc9CJbljt4za0CAnbjfRga7nE3ib3COaymFApqrQVysIMLDqq8vQwQ@iYjm8cRcqRqRLCUhXoHcOu@CHenj85ofxg9aNZqrAeNG8yYYPDgcdmlaVsG4RWHIRC/YObM@06BvgmYccrsjJRoJPA9g0n@QZ6DD@9eistXOUlpTJTUgZghB8VAMUyiroSHKopvXFV1M58Hige@zTWr4K3YuLC5HqdZ64pmh4@CVRz7F1Sxr1TeCEHWlsDEeS4UHXdc2ONArgLkwC@4CwOBqMtqfIz1ZL92fszXE9r@rve0vEe14cB8dz/FBmf0h1QKLyRY82qAOTfmS3k/C34bH2pzYzl0H7K2P7E4rxOQIhBMFMM7NMJwPAMu3OWaZ30a34Hue0QwJwqEUjcERt625gGXqByRz1whDOGOlo6NW2zuiqM0Di2dzzImlWwiDkLLD69pGJ@15t44Lsuq4@S1D/JIbGBpyYUbaHzGDYpz5gxM@OXDLV3@a0PmsuRZ@G0WFQCzdyuKjgkbu8HSjTA4/@U@Y/Bf8p858uEg2SrU@bjCVDpzkWB1s9buANQiKYWRBmznSmL3woZODDicJAYMjZktsc7k6Vxg7wzWxQj9WgYUCbGAHCjYRUf9moN5q2Z1ykmmmpD439/@3uW/fbxpE9P5tPgchOm4ypm5M4iRy5I9tyounEzrGdZLKOW01LlM2Obi3KF3WS@Z3dD/sCu9/3EfZVzjucT/sUs/WvAkhQki/pnnNmf9szsUgCKBQKhUIBKFTlmBDU4wT66JhpetlOnkH97kV3OIgzn/pwB02zksYbn1pnmhuEV9DGpIOYMYReETz4nva0xYkoBLrBBAF6GCVCNaiN3chbTwIPcCIxzlEupbEgdqSROWbtSyfpb6QuCemFsDagYwsQvidNIjQpRZmRI3GjjXT4MBpQHpM3z6Fue/AkuXy8TJScGioia9a5kyys8nmDJpEd6mp1uikmnbriaCrJauY33f82@ve@G/0OjYv52DPDyoSx7thDBUa@pELo4cJUVRtVq18Jg@KDoBuOaOaqi36qZ2uq5kHRLDOkHjQhvozGrTPX6vyWJ/3DN6lz/VwlYYVJtUpNnFRlWMq4MCQVgifFYl1sYhhBlxcBQjBKc4uFutiVXeyqWhXBoa6uKXZpIXnFSF5JEcl9dQ2Sx7oYrZ4aZnpB9xyTdgor5BzBK8s0SmrQMKfi4CLEQf@v8HKLkwxdZypzmAs0D0HFBp@1jufWfmQhbQmtKQBgxBkApIUE591xxZkWeOV88pbIKCGlkVHyptlAZAUxGIvgdfEE7yZMxmtgUvhzKzwP0NjNrRw5uTJvR@N/JfmX881H8688@7GUzVnOfiz5U//7D/l4DMpaA9TSPsqlRxDIWMm862sXyrbOsahq57TAIa3u5HKg3DnKNn0vnuuixZPu4KTYC2Cwg8D08rUwnHhm/YDzHPViOBgH48GjRxVZNEXMdvPqlzVDdNofIJ6lFQ2CdL32IIz7y2Pq1NbgtB/Foa/gqPdzqJcdoY5P49h6sn4cxI6jbcdkGQvQwldQdZvNqB@Nm00XBpxeJbmNwPacYM/lZQfrX3qyypN40kD3hu7g5NewNfZuh4nQJrrYYdT67O4NdSI8v9QUybAW6f@UekYajIoH6cqRwyZAlT4ZuxzF6GzQG5yS1nceF7AD60yBb6SwgVAwHDIuvgqwpK1YAW54lLgtP/B00Z@@u6j6adUNvKT8ahZAhhi@Gk3TGJQdzamueW11UszUd/D9@B7Y@B7cjC@vwqdxlqV5VRK/r@qHbgqBMqZoPLwdDTSd5FZ7Bp0MKsln6FVS4M4ottkgrg1Ma5S1prMXOsQffvIW01uC@Pvr6H9zB5ri9bt2X0DDXh1MSN70YJwtXpticyzrUvaGB9kzW13C2tt3rIvyIvr7DlQIUmNZcPXh8Z0GJuLFxUnUIgP4Fp6HDdoM37NhWlUS5@A0uvDV59Xru2i72Q67wSRsuzqnb8E1Ld6nBRvLq7s1HIKOhd5A1nouzV1ekkrTOIgumSrXsEzgX3je9WwlWaKEe3innDFsXE8/pM@IZmzxVWW3mtYBy8uL2I69iLD9iTh5ElSkK/FntRyV@Ud6Eo5gbicI0UFmz7KfVuvdJD733aRJd5gRkryFbJPh899AhIu22T78PhLd3lLqXKtQ1fSykw2nNb/Ho5t63OIKw5Ny3HQ3lryN6e7McxarCbBUhG193xQyAxm2JK2Wa0OULzf22KA/IxPwjffp@tfMKs05AjUpyZJuHPFym/ULz8HKuEG/2HB6T78AeBqOm8JQpm3Y09Ih3RWn9IKhpbXoL6SkExSLikJyjYaVyzHPlP3Lt6TO1rV1tmbqbGXqTEZAtkork9PKVKl7Ad1zUxd0w874GumMJKyd6ecmsU3/9QfBCLsVX5aj5Urkq@WL5QoJ5OVwuVJ3SSgvt5cr2/wQL1cO@OHzcuUnekjH1vLX5YoZFsgwold@eIHvWoTjvbVc2XK9b844@BzGpt7CciXpU8rzo7wyRYgUaDdpjThi6w90M8ejkCY2Vip9BY6JfSyfeB/G538l@r8EyOPQWUjEHucDzqxWVDkzaVgzhtRD04YJzTJnJFf0bF7f22FbrCQLqlmhNZ5dhsGTGr64nBVGghhS@USDfglByM3KfIyUNZPdER1dO3Eod3K2fonTyvpA2@X0I8p8nFbCURF1edNfWRDSgXfDE4Wvw3MGHVMdY4QzWW8OWiDqL8s3NAp9ncVF977dQ7zXnc1E2OZNFuklBmvJdNLh@HCOI90Ohlkm4VRcK4jsMrwpJ4MS3DtVjKWCHpnXJPNn3TIIBnvwezc1xyoH1DIiCIlHpWMZZcm8wLIYSamsszRVGXyEgiVzaISHrc8ccXJbP3I@ETc@zxXXTUOmrFTJkisrJqlwAY7tzoOx1J4sXutwd/d9y1dT8gp7LS4AWCWTWkS@Dr5Dfx@I/m4UakOEqQrmKdbzp9JZ9frGWXYK825a7WwHItFX295c5SipISU5rQ4szfwmXptR8WHyIUq@VJpAn9L2DdmSNcEtdJteWwgsaAmji@zHz6v08fPq9YSa1Ui6FwWjtBRQk4YjDU8wTZt2M67S8HldjBTe3w66393Bo2wH250HeNyA0RTJZZSPzvts5ZKObRLb8gUitVxRIsj5uDTp5vQjiXs@uk2ObenDXnN/e2/39UeadJ88eeLpOXqS4odRi73WZB4XyGzYncwHc5Ytqz7CwuGwG9vx8dlgNL73qZ@bkSUirEkZgIMXw356jHtallnyfGrsUjnJa1FUw/qcDoMgI5Wg6gSYsiNN1zERJBy7DwINxKi3RG@fV2seB0BrNvtBD4b/mL6aTRgvNZt6FkPXmBNx7@@L94rn8YiDcEv0vkvHYS8santPfXhVO1SHr@pq593WT@rj3jv1obZ7CMcZb99tvm5sKfpX3z2oKydjgodIp1hQEl23w1bI0cFXS6VHiiFvDYYTkTvuliffD4KeejVohTimeh4HvRdn8lLoh@MNKVWn5egEe5gRR7btRWPYW3AoVlrGQrlp81VIXFFQlPeE1rQ9rHl7g3bUiSivg7XvMApjc3tOdSPqQZK35r65L0oSoq6y6RBHU4YF1iUVDyg/zm4ITCD2VyAxckiY1nZBacIl/303BQ/r@28OFLy1bO3tbjcOG3u7B2pnb59e335s7L4kejYODvcbm@@QxBnf7G03dhpbNf4gCJQKCm5Ufj2PxzeiUEB2pkrrM06@C0Pq/uQtu@sNDV5dBnwpNFbL531InyjoRr@H7eV15zyG@oKLqHxUoNyl2v7L9zTnq/A3nHCao2C2P8i9izkS8FJJPefaaLBs0Hhb18OVpr182ePziN5EIRhYuM4@U1x@9pUBzkY87ShUuS3YqGDvW1yr8Fg2oKmiewQboIzBSlVxEL/lZf85g9yg2lrdATwGS21iRKhfUPSFMTVZd5hi2lYGQHHXotHHflB5PflAfE8fVnW145FkUA@TD5JBPZIPUEUbsB1Rj3WO8/HeOcSzWpMPv/aGO3wsrJ4kHzYDXsU@1ThJv3GXBuokjU3fG3Y5VKPs8nA4aXExhCIx50cYw25XBkYoAXRJJspRItu2Uc4cCZsOjhq02ZsEpkcqcQPshILOOFZu1SuoQxgHhf1IgmSedoO@mEClpjvMe@opXJFV9Z3zKAkuybdXhgNmQAS2zeKRlNvWWmF413JUcnOmxkDbSHKAZ2OCdhsCmzMI/BEwBCifWem0eKbie7oAM@hoVnbjAXEk9m3/Zucndm6ft8JMAW215f4a/f67p4nsZ9ZJxk6RsaMu@j0ckVrJR5mdwYjGOItVDscHKdg6GwzHkfShm20BnzjxNEe5MbFRbb9UNzK1gQ7TNfYHfavSE@Lia2o9Iaa8S63M8XJ2noivNE47cT5NwmJ3B3SCk8FFaJ2d@ThEugyx/UKKMJ@VY/NzMmZMRP90UtnxN4Xwzk@rG9ubn/J/@8VHjGcRCxJi3Rgd4h8xJuqi4cHnfGywOILepUeaic0Zn5@gtLbB09ISo9wAo3XgWUTruhfN9SRNzI1nv@Nmz/R3/vj1a1VK5SGZRCKfx2duKt18dWSq9LnMsdImIJbsJGRJ1rvmi88wE3n9Atd50AvrRJE@5AjW7VORL7UIMa07Oe@QZNEByHV3J/A9tcEWFUaRFGcUdn8Uf3Y3qysbXjE1KFEWOV0jon0Duex5llkKz1cz4LZvBkfy@@7gnt6InUwP3wVt@0Zo34VbfuV6WDItWbDuDvZvN4CVye0PgaW2@9cDlklyFlrC6Qlz@kuLiTXtzTX@MtN3PPYIDOZe7KAkQK3azvt8RG1877tSwLPBpArRweF2fX9f5WR9QmVJ7mHJ0NZiELDvqbeptW3UZ2FXSJSmZLGcKE/mS8aizfx302CeS7xrRIXWQXxNj0RYJPdwaEF3JVJPzyysQrD1PQtEQ7ksdl@MDIqPNOBvtAYkZNNOsxrozG3mokw@UWwbgWu6@aIb2zb8bGEtczfCeo8mNiDbJig4xc2S@f33QfTjiqlHFCw4gUKD26RJ03xD64QDqnhIGQuFbA/e0C2mS2FkLwr2oqEdDL9KWQ37zzMUM5Io4aILW2JdK8caNdGPl4yawwaJmAYCWHrqRLFopgQj4vnLc7tDvXTSc7NTECmZCPT8wuYKKn78TU9hTI1knqwmCrk91pYYmyOD5TF2ZzXs9esz3Yct9Nq0eJiuiqTtjVXl/zFVySyRqcnQfG5jTCJBXnv8@OFtsKdbYYrn/yxsmUOm5ee4N6T1fQoynsS8vU@c29j1TXrKADeQTkzrzYCZKkiqzpw5JdN2noxs/AgX2RciZBC5ArGzp2v11NUUbvOhy4xkQ@csM22whnDSUBk1M9T/dnN1EMi31nfv@@uTwYZMMB38Bqv8N4NRHKa38iwnNNYnXMvPfgtHoz5nk/tMPUBx@RrTjZft@LadGLxKq5DI5212Szr6dpKY3fpmr4Er4e3FwuVZMMbu3vr09l6@vG43dafxuq4esGvWTmYvMjfKeZbsuRf1b0KAZTDvS2D64Dt89@MK/SMcfAOSyMS3@VymjXcrbkwR0pqPOCCZNgvVsrU83fuduBX04bbEz92PVc7/gQryLmx9b8ebt7NeWs@UJ@TiYd@lUn4uX8hxUfqGDV1AyoKQ3sR3a8LCTQ1jKYnrNacD2EfhYCu8kt0ztpwMiuWnpbVnDreu74/93tGzY/9Bq5pTNPkG/V58Prpsfz4dnF10VFcNfz25ak1@/02px4/g9l2t/iBuvctr1SJ7L36i4BH@WYk5VyP4I7soR/j2gsS1VmpZpevw9XvK4wdeNFdwQ2KKS9WDnuFCXLEbV3tHa8fVfrW03jvqH6/jkt94pTpeKa@4@PADzaIkY@Rk/mh8jDnV3nUN@xcKHmc5arK@GqL4agh9eROMosHr2u7LzG4cFABsgWlbb95QZ/NkZwHWbLh7UuiHl67eJvMVONaBguQs8K2gMq67834ytmPaEWFGveKTNhtf8d@J5yyUCufD8YBTjHtKsJb6Gn11Fsw1phLvKFCWo8g4scT9AoKT5nFxMCRfJ2JFnS@LulbG3UnPAnGEkiwOc59yOdwpBKL6LtfRsRMXwqB1BiS6pFZ/5WK4m4w3YrW4wLt4MOUIRnxhonSMRxyA0M@QTxtQBWvuMV/7cKj5eC/jQb7wHtWY78mwgbzDmiJSYP6tvvD9Ji7/nAgghF8Qnaugtzi15kWKpNwd5M0FOHPLLvxxzIBrldIpC2gsYEt91RQ4W4ozjVCtJhN9X7gEOYVW9J9uQb7MbzPNSPJ7kp1JwufU@i0GLblLOWkDP920mGsVy5tiJrNFioVbqYGdLloevQlpWE3UVtjtEtJCi4WUHHjk@726/pWk/vgIdR4nyEt6fiY9n0kvSLogleYq0ASfZqrYmXKLX9J831QuzebP1FVVrLwUqKdbBVJJ0rzrN@WNC@NBM0ozbyRdKVyZJDzPJOStlJ/n9L6k3MuUSRg8ST@SdM3fq7rnEywzeV9k68evozsoZONZbWsyxaWFftT9USatJAVsliNqKiXFOZKrMoOqqu9ganFCGhz2@XnYblRTKCtlI3F4zOQ2nr/IFbSS8aM7jYbcYpwZWHPGiEUlrnOFCXfFFxapHk6@Z4FgmGA0ZUbuhik80YUnFljkumeqlVuQMwOcmjY9xKu4F/kVf8xgzyJn8i3OT1wQzK@k8XK7OUsgFrr3cvPJlJUmuC4iH3WjbphF0ron0xDnC4ldaxc4qTOUO9gdbIPfS@SELSiMpJihe5KiKZ1mKBv2va4LkfjN@XvxgfMyIB172A2vVA3LjIBvYTmZC@7jMB7H8EnFrnHi8@Gwi1NHVvgu@Qq1Diex@hjHLSlEa2YvOA1Y9kh@H0/6QjoVKqg9QL6EgUiaEJ@fnuIyGW7ADi4hWrHjEo0LTq0/kQ0NGjMPV@WaeajgfIMFcDc6tZGQnpPRA0rHw6AVFhzS0WLSfhxpaifSAZB5Px33RuD5jKa0iuP8y3nU@rz1Eue5T8qlh2WLZBf6OLhUePgovWBFRDIJq3Bx@Lj8yHGss@GWnA3nAdBXrzHRvyfeDC/Cfj90ajRjcMaYlNY4HF2E7YLj7IfJITDggpVxMol72IPzUUs2d0jpCogZcUs49uU4jDgMv5if5bi4xWdlvoNDq/S0mbr6ImqDgObGSWeA02E@sICbAKEHCvXCMRHlgaeyKPHZs8aFdZceNqKIGvBzYp1NJGToD8ZRi3qGd7KcLoGSY5C0sn57ChOqr9UNcDm4MA8BXI9JKWAQMEdJN@Hg6EPz78JB6YaZM/bA9EyRpN@AxwoN93AUkfRNCcy9wsUs3KmDD181DtTB3s7hh9p@XdHz2/29943t@rba/Mhn3DgoZ0/D6tXea5IuyWm6nJrv0Ydc7YBK5jjBqe1@VPW/vt2vHxyovX3VePP2dYOgEfj92u5ho37gq8bu1ut323z6ThDU7t6het140zikbId7PtdqijlpObW3o97U97de0Wtts/G6cfiRa9xpHO6iMpzq19Tb2v5hY@vd69q@evtu/@3eQV2hYc5242Drda3xpr5doPqpTlV/X989VAevaq9fTzV078NufV@xkYDVys06YVnbpCUsauJ2bjf261uHaFD6tEXEIwRf@@rgbX2rgYf6X@vUnNr@R18DPaj/yzvKRIlqu/am9pIa57i3UIX6Zevdfh1uk0CJg3ebB4eNw3eHdfVyb2@baX1Q33/f2KofrCvn9d4BE@zdQd2nOg5rXDXBIGpROj1vvjtoMN0au4c0Z7x7C3sHjzr5AxGGsKxR0W0mMMwg0Foi0t7@R0AFHbgDfPXhVZ2@74OmTK0aqACLiq1DOxtVSEQ8tJupdusvXzde1ne36kjeA5gPjYO6Rx3WOECGBgwyPhLrUKXvuNXoJ8JLHolZHcO5Pnenauyo2vb7BjDXuYkDDhqaW5hsW680zQtwJmxtokQD7BkEPXtjpTP76SKEY8zZHZn5ezSJx6Stve06zcjayVUuTXhHs87TKVdKdhrNNEkivWZc1rTDk/PTZtTvDHDHNCkmGx@9@NRHDC8PQYc@OTeE0NP7K1xgcbHZfF9r0kL3oNn0/LuUzKBxWwm9DX5TLk@3EUEpsPLGxk@lInR/niHUxg/6oJMN9XAAgZxC/R/E9C3ohZ4qFtuhLobL@wBsto5iOTY5w1EKiUa@7IhoSWmVvDPB75FmBy7oGvCFVhP7pLCM5EyDmP70v6YvMjlYH0g6y3ZXsYhFLKMR/R6aaqQSdonAf7RHgqjDVRbiMPx86pbs6rDmL5wOBm14h9VlOO@Y1oGnrndL8ZPwdKp4fro8I8vHzjr0QmzW3azCJOfPmmRK90thxC1z8ac55h/PYCM@H7BrylXxZrXetHR/kOKwSPKVdm2B6xXcydD53tT@2viA1Vxp9dH61PdXyXcZW7AXhG9dmvCOuNwx/7w6lgw0wNgXB5Ek0h4yikWrjLE3STJfUsYzZLqM2rD8obn6LOR5nUhCiux50LXrxGw8iq5s7EkOv9yvvdl8t7NDohPYPnr6@MnaupO43fqrL78fUQ97uWWvY0Oax0lP4yRrlGyR4sMjxXJFnrI/M3CxiIzwUG86jT/Cz0Nit5G1ZIIgQ3NjhA7rw0QvF4IOOcUOOO45hl/njkzNAG6mqR5a0wuuWMUPSFdiHtDGLN0J99oV/gB2MvzNEE8apBlIsxj7/SXOpdUFy73cjjEV5cUNO@5BlkLO8LG4cUtowFtdbD@L27X8pnnb6sVYTBkxXrnbuSQhcW8aC2XsKvoyst@ynxG9Aczew@jLXzW/0eNH7eCO3d0F8bg2PiAy7iQlsU@dbkbrRh9pyMeIGAKnaqam5wq7/J5Gisee3k5OHINYo4FRQbQc2PhmAa8nfkSmq2QL2BfLnvoinArnHYCzrjlWvxPnzmuOhrJu/Ifod@OVQgmsxMmJUO0yqcMxWT4mfiwMOTNk@lP0YPj/RJrMgf@cVpwEPaWW5QTwTpRkqEIrWr4yUaJLc9BgnW6k1LQ/fUzBfLM75ixpmD69uZL7NUQC3TsT8@Ejuz3suHMIACbHxoY9fhOTtLOAlk4vcp4ujnOSfqs3dJWeK8xUMQM3v3bss9rlm7MVvHjKk70mq8LXVFS9kIXbCY96WjJNLeXV/Tgn4Dzj/6P4gDdAkgHPXHomVqvTnFXSo8zIAe1qyZpw2onHJFJLv117avdAWS4yM7Jfn3wZQhHoDeAz204OnTJQYp6b9bjIM7E6ZC948GWOZTImH@2y7oQNMbsh4Nxv82YIoquMLzFBdAU6u@pLoSn3PhuKoJLU6jD1Mwhx6xWItDytXibY884kODTB/l1f/OuHsqtlchTEwYfG0L4uX1Bvggmh3L1bs4XFig8OBj5sF1GZbEvo8ogk0xoMRqQ6Bmg34ehHE6@gPuhNh7Afn4@0/0Kaz6KR3pEwSj9VA7VJVu88zYj/ekYtjsa4rdAuMH9wk3ohLETFPclVfk25xLyGRzfMpmN0tVJW7vM05TnRhN2SMhGfqzWE1OVcQlDtMjRkCkZxsrhgm02uB@cOyfC7HIw@Y@6HCtRvh@3EM6kFkvcCpZMaffbx2BpL04eDmHc0qCuwA5JQoiwbaYmhKs3RTzQ7abumXOodE75LuSXfX0/CpMZaiipKGVfXTsy3lqfOBJVWtWvQxFloefUxozJvwfXt2sUYewvNHlur3Kd@IlIqokRU7xvVEU8iN5Onj3jSm/zV@zFGD33BGbdWQYEwdFacq87KOcYPNgUfonDUtvdESZNpB0Nsv/HSZ9BnXjRbh9rtXysYx@GEVgCtYnRVZBhN9y@Ds35za9ANTqNBFNA6Dd7nr0Ti4XHCj@iw09HgMuYgSRKt08rUnqTP4l9G3LDhPTmXXLdcc8XjcOjaZgrj0aR2Jm4ieOccRoBpPF/m7@G0j7SkzKPHaSEne/@U7fHK3vq1ZR@W5xWWE30A0AJuY8qCQu6QjvliknX5dH0mw8lNGSwcT1ReBd41FnsZjJ8RifgYJoOxQWbGLMFuBFZm12J81L7y2@yDcARHS@F2iJg9scuf/QDh2kmK/AhLgYoqPy1ZReUU5Qp@CPEwuZ7cq0/@ydgTAn8C/fLDedwyjxFYxHWMt6VY1ivayyjhwuaBEctolsQkxaLTqG9dP@TYF1fTULPJk@uowZY/pBRpN3szXIkR6dLCB7H83CaJnObEw6SyrJY99tsBFaQ2dkvXM2x4m/0sD34c4srOGQTTlobsWkhfR6oWUQmhpafMa22Uxafy7SNmdfWuvTZFwOo8kzMrerqbM5oL30CJZH7FsdZgRMI4N0U9beqxHI8Hw@U7Uu9a2THXM9s8Wrc871ZDYGG2Kk2WD9pM2uoEj5N1ZxqfKabJUowtzYiHsHzl54TNp4l4VW1ivFWbk1vocB3NUrupZFJJ@rstYx@T4gUses1Ekwwpxh1OSteT70dNanjzegmiYcryqskSowmR0ZzIowVqikwJle5OIeY@jfsUPdpEOdTbJtrZ/XMtUaeN5IzLU5OUcXIJesJxOy5tklwadmB8ATdxouEmQipROK/8CR/llfMncDKMBAEIrTjMp/tQsoObdtYUH3F0gI7bhLVQGZKInjZsC4fE6X9CMPbKrzd3tMVDc5IvH68LpKsEEq0qONdNkMx9c3o9al4xlBlS0BCfQ4qkRTOy6ezurfqzbaF8BEFKc7K29C35aIynVggb@mMnNa@gA6dV6ZKZEZUdCE0WDTQWaJVy2g1luQrtLxoJx8O6QQ8jWkDIZxc/K7oE3HmvlRJqo8hVe4Isnia3jDZP5TekSMpQ8g7y66Eoqi4vXAlAKBhT@WqZIMCtKWOPQwF2vWNzXgZR3UdUsFrGsKSP7BU1tfOckw6i6gyPHls5SvNyPLNh5OcCIcVifp4UEdJZ5mdJodBENxcXK8eT@e1Jc5BCbHhfKE5doXslS8Ok54SAHH275KUS5ais/JLmYE589NjLJCb8zanPSlZqaTqV6JNgeJQvT6c@LWVSM9WurmaLZkoSPTy71kwikcKzEU6kwp/7j6@m2C7PE5tQa5GR0TK0fTaio9Mqk9ZthV9j9ZwvZRsdw8Czb4ab5VdTQqxknLLf7IBdLfORAXy3/@nWGstUg4mOFcB@6cxlF1cWhKyx5jDVo1lY6RpPe4mDArOmHXTU@8OdnYzb15OJMTTqhaPHpVIJTHxiO783ttXYSooGxWzuYue82y0OL/8yen9SZNkfhhwSoGJW0CF1CQ2KuDAYnUpkCOBAWZE7ry@yYq1/3unYIRhwQonOo26TnNobguIJKEqMXt4f8gYQg9QT7C9oINr3i0pG32UgiqaGYo6hqDRMgi9y5vSMyIMPHdhnJydVDAyC2Vgz0bzlVTe@YAZBZBPuLHZf7H1JzZNzr8Jud@CrDwizDE8BC9@mC@zs2AVKkgUnjHy79zxmf7S@Ci@irnWvGFlsXgc4MzGZOBPGLzx84@@Hp/WroZs7@jlH0wo1eQXNXIF/al/lTnOedhZ/B7DCh4T2nXL3gqHbYjpNZ6apXo/g9Ikwelj25659Mlk83hPTNLs9N4g6H90CO2ugpnusCxhf9ty93JJrsifEzX26KndAw5LA0DjB58rdSuCq2T9PLF6MO527SUUOAyAd@10SUSKh/DmByGcAPAL18CN6wov2T3ka1jtTDkVEwUGwjlm5gwJNFHCc@63qb5durVZTS8OVFVWrbdJDPq9qmzW1jQ@bm2qb3jfx/kN19fHjdZG5294X@rhpPn5TmwSDdzhXWmejbXqltCrujcFaG128VKwu@etLzerzjfW4eFTbxLV@evr3//rf//2//Y9iTb/8L7xs8svRz0mmQqFQXGp9Wfrh2zrej7aPl5dOjpaGx8un6@Cyv7PX8EFjnA9S89HC6MRZlFnA@sp2pGadzd5ndFFlYvn1gtFnki4VtdiKi4v6ayyRo1jGLrZC63uIe5QntIQ3QQeml/IOgrr1ggm246l3WiEM8Gi@IUoSLrADlfJytmI27uEOJsmQnKosak88rLNehLjTknpSwF1cmrHyUT8O@9gBv2CdV5rnOAH9RuOm5t/iz2/i083BlXrwyVUPSuqBrx7kcvxTXntGX72lYoTbuZKNlgO5nE8p6dECzAxVHLGix@sHjrUzRW7HWeKQPYBk3FRwZrkF5yerP74sIwHX4lNnARE/lWyR8CETiix@Wep/o275Qjm@5TJXbVhRaOpVDFdmnagk/QsVKIjFECCtuScEqQyoSpz08Y1kPBXNF93XDkcTYsAg6/7LHR73@EBz0VJf2zxn1lIIc8Tm8/IVc@O6XIZmtJEi9acI8IGKLCdLfJNweXHZEStvq5XcTLmFbbdPM5/YOkzCsbFNl0J/UxYTiDW3Tbilvr7Xog255XhF5aLkeMWqKjdt@60cq0jvvDuOhvq6AteOAfUlqe2bjCT0KAMSOOKzvzI7wnijwHiKmuoWCZY1Ue0Bmi4joa@vplMHewU5ObKIUPzZpbH9dWpse0W@JWLYQXiAkUpM@TpB1I2115URE/s0GJ0gOmDQ4YBqYzk34/08RG2dwnjQSZAuMGQ2OU/HMzVlcTgKTnuBrxZ3B4ejYNKgaYs0n3Gr4FEL4YIJSGDw6arnNc8gLC3SXcIUSZrClkMIXtCd6PBo0re55M4JutQMBe12BYMgw05MyfBrpq@m6Jhy9Xd0go3yjPBOTiO1iGXJC0sjDSlnX5vhYTYzdBxTgz12koGTcwTVZGQaXtCFzjHR9vjglyR5Fz4CdN05fQtQX0VYe4b6MTudhv0gMzkNu4656F9cVzIvYjxzKEqxRnI0lCflNOIdsCI98uesFwiZm4w7I2fBdRc@xTqc26I9j7CT78QWvxioKAlAxwHM@GaIetePRFhOzVBpDIyCarDlP0HodINTwm9yGUzAip8W3R/vFb2jnz/1jx@4n/pfP/3uMSZaJJtZNq8W9WG2kVh6rNDMWPQzr8YqLTauBj/1sxk@9ZXcYbFIQIgU3aOfi8dfi4TQp0XPe1D8tCgEyXQZMCneXF8R4IszaC5msSguOgveA890vvtj2VM0t/Iv@lA@ePJLWJhFJW/T0zpn1CFQfE/3t3O5chIXn66WHq2WH9FK6DS8yo/Cc8y3@fj8JLwiVSLGcpamnk@/Z7ghQ4hvV3GwTh@vqJ0S1kTunsT6kpIWoXqYcz1OwlZUpiA8QfmJyuwuFVdcvCRPgMNHLPh9RSxn8rIvKDEdtLjPxfwZD3qoJ4gh16ZvhwhHwspAbER4CzUPyCb4ynUc6pnhssz3nApqC75bGQh1b3HRmi36g35eK2teYXkdSjRuzXSflp6WpsfozBDNjNAlrUwt31PljR@f/Nv/3Pttcby4sVr8MKLf8eJvi2tPF@WRHujtoXm7WNxYfI5sa98WJ0VaA9Pjk3/731R@4y8EBymT5/Rn47GBtTZZ3MhXucjXxY01eiivrlK9/@df/5XasCQrNsRiXWr6ihFbNxTZCvrMu5SuGmilLEuXU7HCF7MAQywMaW1OLzCMulp9WuJtukVtVXERas9Xxh5FT/FsmDVmUyHZyTD2FKQZSYEqKsgLSGNC0VGW7YYx2wDzpmiqX@4X1mJaAfyizTmSKhPTjfsxTIaWZFlEHehKjbSel4eN0o@5xLyjkjM2JetGhcTSTsvapw/XiR3eDsJx1MpaSZjh2msFl@FJAXxYCNvntKbqx93Br6PiBbFkr7z6tNjB5n6R7biLQ4aUH04Kv5MiqIMB0cKQjU59NaIeGPTgwsvnaEGk0O8kZ1ImniRp2cOwJXtY2ZjElEXu@PlyPIzmFFJV2uW/pMAjcqYOBGnFSvvUp5J7@xWVW0kySj5e83rA5i0bx2oXGHmxhh2ybCo43AbsDpr2FGqjU76ExKXgdV2yFIJ2uxnoNNdZyJlQab6zcBZ2h9VcR9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNvBZKPsIOQj7Pgg6weuE4oCV6NcdfsB5Pa4CbFH3WmriKS8na0Xn1qr5d5agrN1R9KVVfUo9CS0jrSXjG8sam7GwiW6rYqhyFTRypza2YaotN0OZRgX@AQSzd0ujgWoJuDt@AJKqlzdFWZXa3@bwWJh65DOXOnmwtSuRqZzG9/OibHHKDGroT6i1IZSQg4AW3Agtlej@QGxBVE2Y06jviz28q2fj30GC4DXtwJWq7rRPnozIt9S8Q@yYa811KRSTQfmVtG2xHZo8EdOJiKwlBm8PGS84DS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEyuVkn@qopZLwsh0dvVYCRdCHXKm8@vDR47UnT58hytmCbu18MChUwCpgeBYQDNaoXVpk43u1mlvOySeEoJ6tEtDngcUBHMy6Lj3PuH2@9O5VyyUNrJRjWJccRkOK6@1KBplCHIUFzAi0RnFHOdf9sXKEhh1/antf6R/xt/EPyAxn3NEGQnqrH96mnqmcnjgcqLJgZqc47kN4UPF0ip03HHT24W0ihK2rsD1V9BoeIMZno8H56ZnNHQXt2uqQBgwRnP1SYwX1MhynDsYsrKCL6g2HhnX7omrgHc22AEa5mBKg8wlwGmbab2WgLU0xOpZpEoJnTdxYxRGiZTpqszNzZ3@g6rvb04gt2mHoGG7Btmwl5Y49mcGBDGL1Ws09JOpqbxd8lVTLJD/jVZkFXAn5ynwdPsBd6RYCUVtUMbKa9YaxexNZysyLqWvTtCj1I/CaA7Ncup2U5l6raQUIYgSh3k1KhJifnOfYJEtxsjsZ4xS8nKtYNqJvojhmB3O6spynLUo5E0cVWHCuAYh9m1JOGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIScr1XBuTg4zwVa3sTjARtRxQwu0v7G75avtOv3Z@bDtQ1HerP2Edichnq/Ht6zxLVdUY8d0ge0tlm1uYTP1G64oEbOUtMPYFEEI345ERQxTrwH1xo6mvQzqo8zYPk65AuwaaCXc7I7qQQJHL7wHsqAX74krDr6uw98qsnk1K2kSlyp6WMgW180D26LJQlprAklIeQcQq9MgEkctKbcvpAwvFuiseQd67WIYu7Ezn6czLCsLKlLbd4pE9izPXkuZm9hiVbPFagX9eBNfMN/eyBsnYWeg76IlzHELb9z7Y7yRvztz5P@/YI76P4c7HmrueFiB7BHuSNyG841ODsM@mMMxJxOeg5vt6DTC/lDHekUjSr4FgAUeMMQdUkosl9C2a8SJcucnrEzPRzASWn2MiwF/qPGPdOMfVSBz@XE7/H@18fl/cOMf68Y/rmCumdPzWrWz3K3/Y1qcqoRu9sPc7oW6K9m8P9rSNd3StQpm0znd/J/e0vx/UEuf6JY@qcBjghw4iPv6m7lZNJHawVajkZpbFBzttMtFHPv5XOlh7dWu5mjx0Omex2dVaOvqD@P/VOP/FNKInxCGDmcRiW1ospaX5alclhfNknc5FC5ZSUukvcYzutVePWGl6xE9QYmQ5o2tkV6okELuS2J62lRI9cdU@iaTz11xFtmug2Xi4NxaQMuKsOylQ1w0Xx0kc3UtmVe22Qey2jrcf73yX4QMveCzvoVGyKNrL8Nu18wk9hLsMPE6pRtjNQewD/SaI8MqmpyM7Fjf9k7YZeF6qcaOLabmxfmLBDlqw/kfraV60DesqNzYMiLaFHR5s6qCaa5ZXsgXartkmt9k3eI/xKXPNJc@q6h9vTC4jlSB3vDTvJiu01YfP75pDpBSBfxgAJZ8yn/DqPq/)

First two `d`s on line 1 are skipped by `[]`, IP goes down on the 3rd `d` (in `zzzzzd`).

The code (48+4=[52](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#52)) :

```
r-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.
```

Answer (score 2):

## 418. [脑操](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%E8%84%91%E6%93%8D), 18244 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」













































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlstd[*u""]!!48 在ｕ2\0C0+---42ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyck^ x  \;npp ay 23 
 ; ;:
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({0428351c-0096-4fad-a228-34771be2e799}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4UXHh@RFZYHWTLBJPvskiq6qrq2/XVb9UXX3vtUg2GwRBErdAgA2AVWRXseNejUMrWbLHliWP/LyyPJ6VV54Y78TMWo6RdyLsidgvE4755B/Qsh27YTukf6A9JxMAwSqyqq9sbzgWJIB8nDyZeTLz5DmZicyu5g1/@tMEXuSJY80GluMT3/B80nPNU8MVyZ0Z2dVMr6DmOA6h9tzBZGTYvlflEkQhxNLswUQbGKRvWr7hZolnGKRrWM4Z@KuEbE/siWf0GmDLEWIbZ@TQ1s0eYCC@c2LY5ivDBb88IXcN62J04RPdGY00u@eRsWvaPvUtEPJEA0t/op8Qrev5rqb7pmODV3EpitKSrUzIQ8f1DMDk6IbnOYirsgSiyORdDeIbW8b0EmZFIR@YhtsjNBVj12BpUVTy/vG9e5ddc@TzgmOTe5jCS155sjfxnUP/Mv4C2RsYtkZUsSKqlz2LQCffsMpyWb7sVYKiMnxTvxxPmez1@6ZtkIeQ18ueFaJ7nuDprjn2OShKcs90oZi1oDiJrtlQbFioW8QYjf0ZEVhF0CwrKmSPaB6ZeBPNonD2ZNQ13BDQ8zXXN@0BOTP9IfGHpheFo9DeWNMNoWdY5sj0jR6xTAjk9AMsgNrukRNjdua4UPYBTse2ZhDQ0M2@iUHCdABCvFL@0GB4RtoMKo7tQy0hGvEgGZYRYktzCYC/a3QnA@JM/PHEJ5C2nulpXQuQdmekZ/S1ieVnSRf8oEio@9nQsINaDehEQHHssFR9NKFJMxaVX@v1iAwVGtJxYhATqEaTVSW5HLgTxwWqAVSYogAZreAsj8YUShjKrO9USUGWwf8gcsHUapbnBIlZThp62tBoaZkh3ieuM3C1EVCjZ1Cavn/4hHi644INboRlDes6NLrmk@1tkjx4dDdJGlGxiG6Xi4qoTs6hCBKhJznVrAnUkHhJOFA@bhSawyJLbiSrJAlkUWWSz5M8tN8yUQtAJEWugAEYgZpT4C4StUzyCrS3AskBcE6Fxl0EH2gQJC8XklmMvO9qA9MyGOoBoi5h24EwKjzlPMlBs8gVcwx64Fh9BqrTVJRIrkyKJVIqkBI8K6SiQjIwzjy0mALcRbgBYwXSCIjUHKRYVhmyRaOASowVcZ/0tZFpzYIYaBQ6KSikBFghMwpgV8uABd65HN45uMuIbfmK4/aHUBRD7RTQC5Z5grzMiNgZlq8EL2lrS6J8Exkzi94bYvRAV6BooUxKEH0RKJKHJADZ1TJEX5BZRryhYVlBsKGHwWhqSzLckPIS0KIMRSMDTWUkaglusAPrVIFHqsAQVeBxKvAlVQVzDqMAOCyrIpRzMc@iGWreCUTE4lF7tACA7wMaBSmO/FBBIgEGKDUCpIY6kIdaksNaUsgRSD@kpVQkUAPKCinnSblEgJ4VmUD5KJAurEIKsGIF0qMgMqgHClQEBdKkALUVQKrkCoSLEVvJoT@EzUFYII2ShzB5MEPBKUW8IRzUDgWiVCBOVa0saiikTS1Afgs5WnXVIpRuCfyAbiqkVYUqhfVVLYM/hi0DDctYs0vJLCOEhnSAUsG2AHURiFGA9FC8AAtmtRRUXs0aD7UuMn4WstvHoEVsI0UkIwSVMXvwziM1ISkyoMHWAMlXoQbkaFOCdz6K3lIASRPRGz2Tcm8LexAlolApSyvkR9rYX5BNKdIUjWf@MHJTmZsDXNUEzmgMNH0WeUIrzEaeC9diDl1VyogXiOQ8unrAdp2JZy2QRIa8SqMyTk1r4Vambj1D6/VNb/h6kdY8jaRraL5tnixiKRSyMaJqMY8ieiw5lXJxWN8UoC8bDNG0yItaQpixExXQUpIVhSava/Qn9sAQKuVY@qiPP3F96HUWcVaYs2sOBtCDL/AoWZpN2osunAs0hVYuB5176IjUxThdE/r220QfgmwSeVYY/kplgSOnIo6Z1sUuXwBZDbqICnZqfXNKurd12qUsEpijdNKH5jgErq4FjhUujWRaLsbqBqXcq7IcsWe82uJHjmmnkiSZ5uYcdERM/ox349DbfYBdGHbKWHWh03WoSLFgnyk77DbTQLRlCQC6ZAslpa6ha9g9Y2dl0M42xGP6IoFIQIg0nFMUbmmPuRSNR3vVrouyLIhAPcN1CcKCAOxlaf/rTbqe8XKCQtYiXX3o0A3o9/uaaUUJoP2I5lPpAN5JD@KbLSe77zoj2tmMsH@1HGe8RpaB3vwMEd13zoxF0hedvTYeWyBSgbvBJDpIzJlGpXIqwsdjZQmCQBgOChwQ0qhAFDFdQ6e0D7IOoXMgtCwnsUrUxu0cYrkTk7Vy0FhADvEwjD2xrCoIQYZOcg2pZ5xK6MLksWU5DNMQSmggZwUouhqI3ZhymooI021VpLLfcViynjNazhrrXw@jrA9NlJqsM20GpdeHrtWYaiNQDghK4NByyQhqDCtBLAnQIjBbh6Tn2Ek/wnLmgoQLmY5yQqVopIlvjgzQkRwIgiWep4nG3p2mrDuDqkyplRepUsRScolQIneZUMwhH3NgjQVkwd5ER6ph3KZNaxCISx4qAC6wSubG@S5ptTS4XRD2xoEeKKIBAZ9i0mLqhMdaeyCW6xQjCrCG7YGG4onERC0Nav7A6UNlOzMh78CwIOgCt06JgCSInKaiLnKU5FiBRicWMYk@HhNwh04Jquc9uQzyqfORSV6BpzUE/UKfuO6MTMdQEuYIoHzd6feh9r4yxkNAQUY9os90aJ5QyLT2eENbG3M9h7IZfbyc2YVt0wAYG/WW/Sc/TwYGEB9k2j5qjVjxF9kYj2lGKEE0m8m7tgb0wozo4xklDpdYhOg7jojuPcfwaJVx3JOIAWBknjGgDQRaW3/BkkYov0Ndtane0QP@EzQyxI8Rciszg1EFdeFdw4YGpEPdhKYPhYglu0f6oJDHBFlURTRdN8Z@UFscytRMO6YSPL6HKgF1FQJkojfkNnfJ9qW6A6BR/YlJtKgiYdLHgaaiIccNtH6Bih@RVsr4izW7Ej1AnF6KnX@BMEspeMGvScOYNgzUjyirmPjIUJBHmvoQOaKPPIdK3dDm3MnV7INbPHp3RIR@FDemRgHmw4lS5ITpWI9DgNu6ikgcW4irseSAoEsON6DWvNEKzE6USKsXdxUlTQTWeBPSkWM7K7ACMSO8CLLsQ8uCVsanyDs0K6qMtLl4S2WEbHsxEIXdGfSk47HjQstgrGdGBxtokcVqV6Cjp6IeIy2SO8sdLHQcSez2fewLIcDY0qAuYBPDlgr6lQb8AlgZ06GB8zksxliCaaunuIL0ndEOgFUm6FFt20AVTXNnDAlkDzppiGhGTNcFZniKXQXricIuRaT1FHoGrddD/orkoO3@cuQi1uj9SdecXlbUdXQUP/K4U80lfdTRXRA9oBGlkn0vma5Rdxoy5sVLztiXaFD25AGQAolQ5Kk@qP3QVdwDRvN0ZuspfqmJ8VnCT/x@mU@DAQMySY28BwrD5dShEoGVZnQC7ZraamQAnbggwFNAN5oS9JBE9NBckDagEYKuWan0uhq5AO7hEmG6zxSSUDFRxHwUl2H3orgCQmBa4vkVWRSeq1ODEOvbMAcITnNOO4klAr4lJWhAHhwkKehh0YHKfMyPSjfMcWLTgT2SYgJJmpxHIjB0ACmaGBNEEFM3/U4gtNy@HYovG/U6VDaQqYBt9tJxvTYc9BSBUwOwSGWSIBLRd5762DZSacgvAs9ZakB4gppab5Bzf@hCi6P2OQdAQFbOxpocEjYo50fmyaR3uaBtdEQgHlsdiE6m7vM1DkQA1hrq11E1uURV0H2TSFWsvBieor5SeakrFigfgLmGh0JwPUhKrIRTmIKgrq4kEQsauC0q9P5MtwKRgJmgsTNu1IXknwRjXREjygYyQdhor7RUhgSbA8NDnuwd368HbZF5Sl3Tri45WI6uWdR5E8H5MOyDwztHe0c/31mBwzK71csOkpkvF7GrnUyFgT2R8qJa3YzjWCC@27keNwZchuG5wJsIzjQmKs106FymITkfH33@MklAEkJy0BjAjPclkYbBgNDFdTVveKkTJoNMBqKMgoSwRDgkIc7IgElHfy1Mz5PJq1dYeJcTNQ7cMWXWRGMIQkfp0A7Dieh5SQALvbp91iPSsCCLmjZOZCxMccgwPe@i7Hw5MVSgjlWZdx/fOziqU7TB6JpAQSTPB1lKc3si1HlrAor4Khhgf2DSSUZcJBylaprWlQTW9SUCL8qWrMEPCFDjER0iWKMwa94Q0r5/OW/UVdCjGkDtFMNluTIuD@mfNaGxdGAXp6Piu6oXpR6LzipyWtljRb7L3ZZeKBilfCXebemLOHtxpHTeAPqBUG50wevEE9BFXEiRgVgdJP/pgysJ96gQCaqAEKbMs4hI4/IsDrUXwSRJT9oHPc2xDPEDyvF4wqclKRlOHYi6R1XQGPzB1PRTcpq9lTTAQux7e4fq3RA4GLim4xlUaUCNHHsmt49zgboHdcR2LGfgkC0Iw6TDMEIQm9Zmc2/g2FdKSENHzGoCpxOB/@LwjTaGvsZ8RdVHGiqutLKJSc32zoBLK8UcEolSiKKSKLz4kXaqAbkW@X56@MUD6ESUgixHZpleQIJYGEouNOkxV@pABIhIDNKzMoPR/OOV1h56CLEJQMx0wOiigHsL75WOlGOK0kr4lUl6z7lC8Y@c2aWqBS6saoEhRrLDR08eHD46eLj3YctXC4Ule16uFIFwEF8XZCFxyOiGrXWLNU3MFqJLQNtwsXkBF5iAghJOKE08Fxi3iCAiS8CaWsNmblPvOUM76aUvZ@YMfYWPbJ1VoYfY@BhoEBAU7Z6FyojLZraxP8f6M/T9sVeVJGjlw0lXBKVV@kh3LG0g0XDQMViWpKDqcvgYRze8VSEgMd7MYCHYEBeIDjM6jqhZIweUFzo/jqyBpBh6OnZlmYMh6MI4iW64aTGqwTQ3Ug80BNCVpShvlAFTG9A2eIflxLOq/Y6illm9VmQ1L/Eh2FLzB9iNvgGqUwp6KyBF@pKVtG63bpMZcGnEdBlJgohbdJDDI9gXWAQESTp2inp@SBzKLXDUFHkFpdHLCY7pApeSCnK@pBQLEqhloKaBzCrgyJsw0nx9KPiOAPgEp0/HDWK1sO/pmt0XtwJDmFiQ@25BVnPN562W3QYBvXWbpg2nppuzdlNpp2vkapCtAD5dg9q7lD2su6ED1F1qhKpJ32QNP@tpV9lZT6Otq0ckfzQO@hxhTB7ugSD1ygF@3TPibQ8DSHFPaWsJVkLg19KKASELg3L4QEpJ0KCgp4WqJ2G6BBB6UTyEmgN8KxaALEYzIoFp5g@Bf@RIap@a0lclXHTOBVxjOSk4NCyOZ8DyKBAybSGHCQo9aIRjhgGTkgQVCCUe9E@yJNCBhGMXWPoYiokNaO1DRwDqnIdDkT52wThnM2Fjw9gkAysOeO4JXySa8Oo64SKEBsRvvv@DfoAnEttEckfDGgdUuCTZBQFF8gxZAPTlM@LTkYaegWo8ro94ZpuoiIgc9RWg60pudkTf3SA8xPXm@3/y5pPffvP1T9588q03n/zqm0//6M2n/2FDeI06ZmM702oJYrbZJnzySuJvHai39u7culOmKQR5EhL/f//Cr/7tr/3SctpXxPujj7/2o49/8W9@6ZO//sHHP/r4Sz/@4dd//MOv/PiHX32reO3/65cd/b9/4gRRnuHQSDzCID6IbjiEXvQ@SG3NrVtn52RjYwOCb2zsQEls7OyQDNmBpwDPDeg3d8A3C88d0gTfDdIm8zYHGqxHVoz2iXT8XDQ0fdgBbqkbqVxahC7v/GJ6QYbD5lSEdn7C61t8e05nl2hfgDMuLNH7WGhP6RIZTPt70H0z2yLx66JuSq2m3Gq3zlOtXibdmktZpQ1adsfEh5dS001FFAVwQ96SksTz8lyK0jalkAAk6kN3kTI6YcdW7KAuzSr8PXMKPRGwSqhI8TF5ylro5A4OrX7RGA9nbhwgGq8C@RTHnhcLQXC9DPK/OH95xcLHRaElHTmUGBkciIU47IWSxnjG@CLHUtqSltYhhT3WqdAfOb4mvS@CuiHGOprkRlISBOhDqA/DRLP90PR0UC0023AmXnyMbuXQIcYOrsfDCbDv/aE55gx96EBN3wWcJJolQSLjhI/Apo3CYD1dhBubNbIMnGKA3piu0TGh8GnrpaMYCo36VLPMXjSWXSiOX4pRbDUahsgYkTmwHdcQgBAQgqMLkuh6N64RzuYe0pGiK7wy8KVdAPJd0/Cz5J7laJSijg11IVYbcS5kER70WQhyZPQ4yyZCH0QLkZWAa/SkLY7ObTruENgl5AanbNSojEaBh@R4457oTyEol8IOKu7JtCEQ0s5IT1XVol7oV0M/rAtA7CEUDWpxNqiEoZeggGc6KNoDNowS6rSPHt89YGMNtHPC7gjHnTojpzcBOSzQM44Me5AlB1CLTNsZASu1w/CvTqwjx/GZVgyWdSMZTMk0RxNLo2Mkl4cxrg2nO13HokMn1wVdwE9cT7M0NmgT@u69/xBk42fHT@tiNQYkaaeja@PGcbvV0TJ6HsZn6ugsZTid4rGKyW8WeOzmwhWVyFwCjzJ6jHDNJMiKgRZNrZFjAHiuyHOEXatuRHAKhWMy0iKic0Wl7qd@v7/knKPOJwLyEmvhnKfObB3lkjrkdhdABQaEiyqXYOKIihQmWlu5Fq5E4dhyDqisC48y9dDoSksBh@6XfCvUd7HUEqWfgINFE/ZDwwon4I6MkYOTTNBLWjibAaI9CrJsMaQBfcUY5xIom8YZKugSNAh4WdCCJjYWGDSX2KDNpmvaEk4UcZsSCUaIa7ThgNbNZvY8xkId0Izp4MN2g80Io@bhMqVHYmPXmx1Asd2ohYvT1oFhTMlkBEax0rRBCJpNOgl@JavRkgaPDklzNEiN8yQQuqeqLLSmpYP2RVLyKBn6hG@1prdk9UOQSXDZ4eZtaWDU6HqgNfSqhT5JyrCDvpyjUGx4Vx8CdyGZ6TIpoXwmdt@xegKbS4K6RpgWggUUTOhHyyGDVa@G6YYrIelSVBYUuWpsEeUVvJeKtHEVILbsMkKE4gO5OMmeXpDmSZacit7YMn0QkVCeGAariuzLCzTpfJbmutrM44L1IHWyd/Tu@025zTBwIw3nh8qsFKfhOl/Q2lxngiuzwYSrWnzTp70@nbU3Mb8g5EAAOpUAyQccLIIaiSIKckQlH@NikZe@AfpcyqDi0myUJUZ6LvYtzfcNm9U5Nkm3ntxsNiWIpk6j3wmG5qtEpvMXZh9SCX6QxBp5enz34OhIRIEulTzAeY4qNEcQHUEYWZfpkJLxzFfJrV6S3MIwaVRuOWhqoK53gvBQqWtQ6ScGzuYg2xkYbgoc0zhFoYMznRWiAZk0FhAI1ybpPqVRhCwFyvYOQ1Zdmf5n9ontnEUlXoUan6GUBHKnbldRykyLE9t8KXrQvVBBE0ACfQp6ifpminKyTSUdLD4b4QQrCNVUQIQcNJsEdCZ@E4B50m7X2Ew5wIIfuCF1eZ4WBV0OXlfCoq@DMwgyFEMQvP6aPG/KQqWd2VyFii7EClZys/zH8CKGZdSesTLazRRt71caMksDmzFj3PuZR5c/Ln/PUCWbzMCzkVkKHi4uokyHrkVaXlO0vGIJGhmyEjpggRkJWUIiWGcf1FnqTzk/aL0YjDqk0uQ8IrqKJCcXF5SGZFMllIZgUggrjHmoFQNjeuBAbh4Ea@zjMgFtrcFyC2yzLY4PFe3l@Uz0YeK6dHpJJhVO@Xg4JhOa9olDZ0UiU0cWlQLKgVHo0Yl1NSQu2KSPJdAoDQxWXZc6b9Tt08cKADo5EEw7Uwc67BxIwCA6atIRfdER6BUxLy@1WIo2WMpJe1owE@HlDZBCpUyB@92uuQ4UiIBrqML3CjBgUlifVTEvKuGifdOGWm9ZbCgCdJZF1i@v0iFLdA/WnAbv//FxD@h/tXSG0FHg@Fxk6EDXjSUl9NcWVhAULfSxumDZMPLEMjVKGGq6CaWuuZAlzYoMq1HTqWpBgO5/hAPvQYlD3cQHCJzXVDOWcjZvFr5XR7Jq6skGlqmvg720aolFRSdJQJ3rUSIwIcg0aCDKulghGFM2URFTp5GN3ZyocGkRoZWZlftw4k/YE2TeGwvRHON9XdsMIOWC1lUMia3yvqbIXe1k0nOE8ckgklOLK2AXuaejSAKIA8GkaQeNq7PPMshWTYfvdWCLrk06o6@baoVnT7yx0KW6d4/ZaEMYXRODa7HnOhAz@BwuMqynmmnRx1vWxAA7VJRgzYCE6zKFGNHMS2S2tO4MZZDhZ69l0fw7cJy6nsnIuTUTsOPx@vCob9Lwlcrq0FNRZ/RYNTIgsbWfgeJFMxysBr2hVKG7MkeaJai9mHEtM181fX8FNJr5o2HwQwX6tcK1lRw7JH1iae7CdE0VvzLYfGXYOugunpi6A2LAmCglUVHDLiPWUVBWGS4cW0SAS27pI7Y4wFxFvvCTCyEyrW76ju7jgso1dektGBlbyIjLRWOVQ3TWUUh3zvBeKzYMQSVlz9U92auVqXoLpiRYuqVB/722G1gaCsShxhsq6JnpGfSxmrAnKxPq69ZK9@WqHw7yxQftbqrOnmk5HnlKn9cRaOACFdhzdUWO09LUbIEOeMfN1/CecAXAokA1a@BYxfJA0uCxttQnbh/5ffB@W84WcSZFuYEzhWKPYyvBey0/P5Hck5sKiH7U5@Lqz5jxmq51FXsKZjjW5w4UAvy6YXXO7sllGlKU2EDgmohxzcuZNgvfP0OXsY60YZcxnlExGqQ6DFApg8F3mWj9s8SWvz623tsxpStoSzdlIla4J5YBnRR9XilSosrKZwyhyPLbs6i@NTEmxkoF43H3IwO/Yr9GuXj7RMlBNjaDcXmcCsDPNyKoV4FG@Fapxv4ZbdcyEw2n/m4WYZaZ2hik7jGqzE/A8AQNV0MM7Ml4qVSXtDL76HqSDcdhk3Z6S6lDn8/Kh8o3SEhLcrln0PtaTYlpdrh8ql6QZTkQXGLzK0uW6zSoXBT2I5M9lyKmLouYF7A4p@bGjKvjoGSJL9Bby4LUdQo9Ba5UJNu0DX@Gz7fkpl3HsT5LSQFTxY9qHdBSBboQ9boSuyLuBJ9YkMWQhYcDHd3@usEK1tsEOiXQB5Xl6wo9PgH0VqUp4BTnCKeflq2r48DhSEsbdXsaSXXPnPQK0XMpCvz6EweC2LpUa70gGQyBKGJZLF3b5Jh46nQNS2OvaTF/Hb6KmLsW3zLHCOZlcR6Xzd4u5toTlzjSeAaUMnugmgyNkUGt14j2Wg83mAhea4GmDt7rvKeGoUvTA0NfBzA2gSnY@FyaLo5JSr5jg1Ll4xI4VE4sXGQZuK4n4kPNNZ0He4/eXVp7cLXkq@RwpA0Mtl3KdVxzMWiBK32Yarcwrh6@qJI72Fx1CLaIfH0NgQZ2Ysy88L0S4cOZDsU8Gd085HaJEeg4DvoWLX/dYs@r3a09dIb20BiyFdaRbV1bgerps@1trks6pHowxEVf4/HSYvA4PS0HQr0FPZFNMqbpOP2VaTrAj0XxG6fPhJd9mR68bhzA03zGStCwthENjQn0UZ7jO2NDoLZ1oBYO9rDnOn4aznH/rKNI1@r6QJHw/bPiv1HPHGiOPx7TV2dsTTz6oEEF@o3vTTJUny1KocsHHXcgvnJGXTFwFIMVK3QafDXH6Zq@PsSPrFnNNgZOVx@aNyU62NhBCod9mPWt9FikjEmEu@gsWiaQ152JWF/qcf@n@DpcV@jBCBLr6CLDNbLLqlE6@hmzMNZOdI@NiKKJVHFQONYa2cfOVfq5ePXlxPQXSGOrmKIhXjY1gYZ1aQ8WX6yVsujXBAs2HCzKWFtLqcCOwrlgyCD8KOuiXV7XFmtiuRx7rOQZuqOf9MNhrbWUDBb00ME/MzYsC@5LVWdpJdJKbcIeTgbeVV7IRuN7IInhY/3oBF3QGxuRhu5Is4PXOgqqloRf@sG7A6LVxLh2yqRw7ZwJhVMsQXNMeHXgBaUyWTtUZpljjz2J0F870xYsUAKV@/J0IKPNbLXOHBRMz@izGQ403SRvjhwXBPMBSBuCjhPlOECOfJqJFIwn2c4A@LVgkQVwCLtOP1y5gGh18UfdofDhI2Og4WriB6aP6y5X1AraPlYtPLoR9xcmmmd@YQI5W1fZcPMCNsvoxpedom0FvofawNTvLxVElMiAwMGiTfZaqv7odLUszoamhwuWIsM1409Y5VglxlrXAfVgBeTlYflo34ZFA2LfAq6EXjV07oxn@MnUjJquGzU3fTqYGrzXaYjrloddm4izyWg88YLX6jTQJVHxweYRY2femQnIhZfANclQs/zVA9KxkVUQsIL@bmFcHWWVfNG0nAH5YlkmII@BfIVy94qKcwd63ie43sa1V9REGvdbzmrieIbgsoy9hLI1cGW/bfrXD9r4Pq69Cd@YGdYpOGcgDzzAp7j7WTEIx6sp8uBmMX7xfe4NXTfUvKfOxNUNNEabbsQl/iBWYz9cUmziNgW4achZXB/THQuaFxislU1Gd@yJL7gT@9peoXhtr1DFjZdi1YCkvnDw8Fk6XhvowuubBMxwa66Fae16gEuVzLRBxlrPR5ehQzXhLtsy6Iiu/70hzB7ua6RTdn3XWaXKPJlBB/LWuhAw/8norqHjrOCNcT9yHjq2A73RGBjl6MhgH74vreNYHRCDPcBPu4E@vRujeUrRrumEmLShjY0ulK@1ML1NX8QQ39V8bU1XRIcAqWoXmW6sK6bVNdyP6NhezLxOW11O0H1jStWG9RWGtUHB13Um7eKw21IbWZqY8caOY7Mn5bYyvJSH13MV6Aro4@3nwUVcXb@k8q9UvZaz@viULQIxemxnhnV5dY2uY7HnNUuObJNN@WuuaXjSA/zQn7oV80QA6cu7loeUruUhC60HJNlTzaNz8Ku1iAVKZfoZVvgMNVd3cMIrMFyz@Cb2df4NbDpasM/WBXSB8FPgWJo@CfbNvClZ1qg7oo@1CkOsNI8MiKaHKwOfzmxfm14tTDboE3zPH1uwFX0FH7IrbNRFknoC2kj65m4rrgheoqo5pg/KqdfOitO1OIJtGvorDQfEHEqvxRD0kj/kWXpEjWuGpGPNiA4WSxr93HtlS1pemQYCjWUI/tAFdV7yrxvFDvcaWTHtMRkZOJe8PNmyVnR1vCHNrLN62jxirq4hBNveAS@JtsBj8qGwt1byRPTwf3znPQk64U4xH@6/Aazr5ol6SPzEtYPX29TAJ47n983pY0g3LvJfx04wWwUIAi/WMtC0tS4TUHr2xGIDC4PYsqpRj6pjAt2tWBAsyq59QzDsU4Huhja9miOHfb8l7eFGtr7RE4LNAHBCQXgQfsoVgQXvFfOkcd6IazkViRF2WswHqztXEfcs5Awgbzm@MPboWxp7Tw4fPD4Wx56ysn/aG@LHD1fkuKXdBdSyHBtt@khzY9OabLVZz/R86c5TRdh/cCgiwBp6s7kLAV44Abf0WjukGW5oKmlrtSD0NfzVAuL944cPMosvH0lqf@g6IyMd995/@jSLH5K893Sldzz0PWgdfWe6NvjhgaKkV1Tf4PPYddxzRUzrMB0boI1CZbzPNie5UbjSnbHRO56Njfeh80QO7r1l9MW1mXyknZoDbIWkspZQtKGSiljMp2MLr0HZNtzova48T8wxckudviT2WrvqBCWHnOTmVksP103sX5ZiiBwsOPhsgRT5am2Nb6krad4/NmGKoqyj81OtD@VKCmsLaxlg1TSw5Zy@xYyxESgvQuQk@FCrBPPGZeIlYQSsW8IHjrwHjmDsrl3tch2CyLm4ssGfGfZMswU6TXWdeFGF0Lh27VqQLxpvMdcULeQ5xX27V07fRSvmSUqnxvQNER@7sSD7@3cObwpwFNDyeqh3Hz0jTzQPd@K4HjCeYuMtUryQjD4ScNwKt4FbN4Bz2HMBlXotvsF4dXuukqea23Ps2fTm@TX6YSl27XSn1AgX2iiQYZlTc1VfpbNxrSerVxPdFDf7RsOZLcnB8R1aAkRvvvyriiLLdP8dfCsys95QMmEDJyk0aTPc1C3udXwYsQYd5RYRHNIrtdEHxhRXnbDR4FVK/cr@rXhN31dKr@9OrvMrX@OXvya@K37oSHKirFyDsHCNHymIkfcDxzobOuK@5hreyhn/FQm6LiOVazJSiXHnYONwOmcYmNeL@PhlQvBaWVuPDd/Nj4dO18xfs15l@evftVMevubSFS0DJ/i0g9lXR3w2MVZS7aH2arUHZTknK72AGxrDCf304ar38iRoF4Rfwx6YbLdBcsfxD6jtGg0t@ih69XoDc3x3Ml6fYmCSeEzDZb6@BPgBKM/OmUfu4CdwC3l9xSAArodb7b5OuCXRCCFuunn/eC@sZo@fSmosxkUqPnyy5IwfifqPn8bcXGM6Xaf9CtN1yuRKn0Wsj47zS9FuN56friDW@u@KQO4Axhy91wpEjOu99/Qqb0A9buiPrNDnPc1eDJ0uFVjP8ekXhSs9n8ymdNnkypIeslVrq/xc/aYlY9AzmybE7UmdDu4M1Omsq5XHxod0EgLkIeIz@YQhDTbgMqb5YZhCGmRtQ3VOFlLQUnKfjoemPV3pNVoXhq4aTX3krW4Ge@Sp5ZyRUBlezx7U1ci1U2MVZdd@lChUcteLY7lLstW6cmEnegSvdUVyZ53Edoln4KKH67gJhj/SpXuh5X01fSP8e09D8Jth9y0HB/J75mR0MzBFm8ncDOhew/4uIzRvBsMDME6GjmvfDBpWp2r1jvGWidh4a8jRTHfeIg3dfv9moAPPuRno4cTyTVReVoM@ciYW7hSwyu/AHax0b2w3Wi2xKq7zxL3FvaGbXu8PfH/kTDxQhsyIeUYBhY9Mf8kxrDNxN9zq3LBF20lfwvueQz6Pm5qvIMWrtyyj9@6tg1ueuZngXD/98ndhXPcV6HiWu7GRvzIH1PI2jc42R9fCLnafO3Qdm9nS67rHxU50K2K6r1nmjQwtXPmg3rAGAjs05k9OczdzLRAQ7q0vs/dn04XeuZx7i20uscpvXwWiDHQ9HZ7Kg0vRlVxs9I@tMVuzinfR@3/hYKTpXjq@Hiy2q004n@ytkwfiAwrL3frTR3f2jj948mCl7@e1UXc1vw8PsFDvsmWj/dja4SvibTTqSg/8kJ7iU/CGGohWdMBVwN0uLk3Qf7D34Mnqnn0I@i2UKu7QGRulXnTMqZ7raaNKfnU5Pgw/Kr0L7ArN6zqS@zPDESZryMYEt1WjiWs//Lq8F@D10LEd/BCQ7SQBAkr8rA4vG@wZx3ZeYftdeGJ4oEoqZQMfSy@fYRffvAN3tE9t4o7Om3SjDoC9uCAbweYY4MGH220E24Hgxq@mPTFwPw92spVf34Ro6nWlUCE7eGhclSgyjROP1Kyw/TXDyJpk8zzY6qJaVeZko074Kk@CzUai7fLZlu@AGDerhkwR4UQhmz74bIYbZRB6hhG5IHQCQNBxT2CwiVJ8y6BasJUIpGnz/Mnhk4Onx3vHz5425fY82GokzIVtQ2zhhka3cj0eMh/QzSZjdgAE3eLGgujowTU4ceCF@SJ4Ztty1upLWVtkit/BMJvnti1JdLcVSZhD@gSexUZ9USoGJ4Y7zDEtoGCjnSrb@ITu3wJlxFDzNE4otCqRV0U81jwPshX4Xz7ikPri@ZhVPCETIw727IfKP3CcXhCjZ5CbrzDGe3uHD54dHZAwgYtac2b2/GG9UmBHOgS7OfK494pFtyVKBkGSUFb1evJeEgiTFJOkSvfHoccp4M6Pyag@4M46Qegtktqk@IGCyahQpP/xsTRPivhFVRpgk2GikhAt1HlaUXDvy2OoJOTu0eH7B0cE039wlzojiRAFOcbNOf7iez12IFG4ZV54Nqg7ChRZKC3PMXtV3DFHN0gir6jBtls9gttFsk1liDGlh/vQmkdH@WKnhabpNmZcfJufcO@bxfY8WHKUA8RDsoOD6LY30YlF0cFrHEe35YT6fkZ3lb204WqabmrITkJlWyFHqGnVCw8/wdUAoHjTrtX0TNx0B8uh70zcS40Ed7qg@wuLZA@PTcXDWTV6thYkdmL7bH/GYM@2BNRQMeJVWbJJE8tO4uJjgMntDWgkXWNg2sSzTZDO/Cr5CGowzrhX2aZMgtBIXgkSoq5Sk4D6dAyQjQSM8IQLIowPcKPNliu9@ZVfkgY1AmYfzF8NzFP5Dti@Ftj6YP46Mz@XsIJKySsHMEVpiScIN2AOcsASwvXNn/4UT1LmU5uKctJxTzPJglyDh1IrkAK5tdkShM2mXN/d1ICQ/stpC5qztJU/Ne4O@73DgdTieRDF8pK0dX5@nry39cR8XiBFoWeqxZfT2TxXzL2cznNK@eXJWCk2xZfTNl@uZ0/arWabPHny4evO6zQ/PZ29hH4nBRVs/zGv5PlEtULOd4q5xEkFD1@EHJ6QV3Cd9An@qflVL2bW0NztQ71N8iTRauGxx3yJB7aXbMOfcooXcDGe0WyIDXGn/fp1uqlp/hRkDtMce70e3M6QpFQ1/ZRAU7sNjYgFkEiLvikR4SqMpn0y3TMGg8mBNjMn9/xdsSSWRTXGmLYffvGD4Kp98OwZIc/Is2evjtawsXYmkxKEJjVPQ8cHIHZkp6Ta0QoJPD7xL36wMc@eP@ls/8UnI8nYwNdjfH11/hDNT5XCrY2NW3fu5PNZVVWZ@ckXn/z83t5e/m628KRZ2MkL8sb2n//ZxoaqbqvSRtvzlHayeXLyIa/KeV78i@8mO0@efMHzGrn//vHrhoKPEjxOSYlU8MoRBYz4LMOtkEKBvO2VeJVQ4ErM6K@TCN3PN4jS2Cn9z28@fpnwEw1V@sCFt594mSiWE8wIBrDlQttpopHYRrDiPDGT6vU6GEv/8z9C@MZ7gAd9ZtvwaBRCXMVZoiHUaZCLRKMIBkVVId7/5@OPYykEfgaspE5bZHjtAkNsNvl8SeV32nBt0Wubw73KBFmSQjjbH/qGQ5TybeU2WkywwMuGFw6dtRJ4gOzjXSI@P8pAn5AR329sSHe3BbjEsaQoaktRbgP7FW5t1esC9Cu02eZyhdu4j2ya9oYDx3eIcfuDpSvxwT/JtRJN7YN/yuuI7Ju64TpZLlHc2H1xt9GA/OYaua1Ghl5BI6PtrVTmHWcXeM3xcOKaDp5EW3uAZyo1eLms8tlsdveoA0HIdIokFKZTsYMoCDvQPsEusUOYCzbnwJHVRbgayAnaJHJnoULrAo68SDahjbRfrIdLHOD1l//5L7/9l9@kv2/T@7/iRm92z@xLWwB0Cs2lAddutao3GnzD5c9baG9AHZOr5WpZ6sxbqa1mo30EYu27F8lCLkmeWrNsB5sNaaVbTRq@QaNtBNGjvZFYODeYSyPuFngwYOoA74BSJBHmM5aviGqEXILjEuGaOaF52mgLOPRaF5pKsdAWWKjmLhQOr5YqfKedEDZnwInUdkMtqI/JboNdZLjpEQdTk1OLYUaC9DYWeVv4LGyNuFOiEQZrLGA@K1yQpgqXaDaltkH7ikaY0N2N6ka5WqyqUqex/qotQuBFQQ3DeOIlThPRVSNBPQzpmYhqZsztebwkomIhYQUmS2FvgIOyAqYxnQb/NRctrlxR4WuBSe3wpAb1Q80J6qDDywq0tt1OJLzvwLUBP/qHK7Lic4O6BM4U5Oq1QarKlpqTCreKByp2vZcvV2g2MpQzCu1GRkQOKYiXYDjoS4je7XZf6V2QTDStq@ma4msTbarNNL876U67vj7R8YBx8gTFu05ABjfnFJyyE1JFFBK5grKZuI15y6kVPKsbdJNyOVdRcyUlVyrmSrJaLuTKlVwpnyuVAGGupOYqlbyq5oqlXLGcKxZzxQqehw4wRYDJIYZSIVfJcYnXzQ1yxPjblGTCq5W58XomUo6GFzU4eAuCM02A4ARKe5ZL/DNcDUVVyBZ0jjI8QCKkRqLSH@RwXzMnXpYjCRD2ztuvt5qvt0i8tIQgzfASO7vtjDCfN8FcqwX/7UZkrNGLmSCr7Xkms/28ATLQ80YzAyifByhFgVCkYqdB2tvUK4otiC7w326DGCVktpvbdWef3iJtikIbUG4vJXN3l9arXQjZ2IQmn85kNgVhowl4mkFvBMBY@4L8AKZ2CmSV8/Of8SbJvJMsOrvb28BW5tvzxry5PZ9vb8N/mz7nwRtc59tX/vS1uNbALPzbyJJaTanRkloBW2qDXZQa6CJKLTA04A1wzZxabmNHiIKO2P6X@Rezi2fkgklui5BqLrFFthK4z1kuscUlXrz59H/Du/Xm0@@j0ErgZ1S5xDkhXELaqhDqRl8VkNwe2uQhu2ww4x1a0QUdGg/R0WYPG1VhSXohkqpA9eGUUi6mRezpO06/g59Li@QFgALYwcCA9hKyWcKr5SLfySgzlSS2@WKJctafu3Ilk8l/9UKtlJJM3cbvfV94nvcwlspFOgG4psqKoFw02LbW7NyBn1t1/aufW3dxiYsKQRqlCKMLl4BqlJAkUBO5RGN7hItG8cweAQ9fPK1/KDzbE/ad0VjzqT6Og3UgFdQPD@qVSgP1JGPzCW06W3e34KnA/2ADMkFafQBt9ev6CGTwVj9XUFuolr6rgXoOPE3ovsTfg1f4I8c6/o5e4o8cv8LfkY8/8rCLv@OX@Nvr4u94hL87L/H38BX@ng3w1/pcLqfU@M1zSp6MUlHmm1OekqkG3Vmj9TnfnVWNU81K8eqOCjJnusbKNZevpBOtz7GBk2pwDA0u5DV0v6bVK7VuXQ1Ag1VI6COaXniyZ4p9El5VSRoHLHKVguMKOFMOD3DI5CqK4yZ/8o1PPknW60khSY9hyIOb0EWgLgUCK4TMs5TgWWyQPih0z0vWdpOfa9LBqUKl3UTPNnhwiTrZVDYV2ZJ1WekqXTCYRHaJPJSHSk@heptsEHkmz4g8cpQemAz4yWAy5T6RB0S2ZRvAwBdMfkf20dSH1wB@fUDkws/E1VhdRdYJRGShkEqPR1M6GFK@6JB3h47nZ8ctrkmShH9hgAIuKqIsFs02HpbR5F@8aElbbbVSJiJWcrHTfNFKtvkWj1spq5U86c6MjdYLHqQSmWeNAV1IwvNAq68lpFZLYgUAZKMlOp93OgeP7nY6EnaPLWI0MrsZYPe7u3Vg/8FrJ9Go7bSqtPcIe5CEtL3TauQENBcz0Deo4EbuG5ZhZ6XMZ7wWiOHd2KAEaL84ewFKUOoMVaGzU3idhYYPWvDoMCWJektnH7RiVmqAC2El6YMVGJYMkGrbBbWBLGQ/@IM2@c/1N/9l/R8@I2mSarbTqfP5dopeafyl0@fz83nwbKRTqcCS2oYfOoAdg5zPG2ikQOdgaqbS7fR8ztzgmUpvM4QNiGa7QcMu4KCTSURR0mjZI/VP@4aog6uVrJEX/Pa2q1@0apQb5OUKSfAvakRbzDS0WlNZTgPHCvZ5F2yyqV3QYdl0TcdDFDe7TaX959@le/nvpClQIV@rKVuEWdS8WqvlQ1upXKuVQ8tmKlW5ejXkHaUIulM@n07XamDZCdHKYIWwTfI6Q@qkBc/27dsskrJ6cRHizOWLGRlneGq1MKYCRGt4ms7YN8ihh4/pPvjALQoJgkyBBIPUKZkepIFsPclX@du3U8FRyTt76du31Yp8cRG5jMfgpCw5dTo90@100D13ccF3eDo7UCmAXS5fXChyJaMkSdpxU4/wvFuIKyUo5JbaoNFWgGer@RJ4BykobG8X841GMQ8uxTIEhEwxjl0jST5Z4xPnNBtKucT4GF9DZ5KABg29pnc@T9CSJPlCOgU8MA1S5TyBPxfZJeuuCoV0LS/LifM5z4CVSoVBp0m@mCpnKsGvvpEmDRCZ2A/lvlwmv1Xa2gUJGn/edNWFHLV2btSVef3cqOIpSvOaHpwmit@ZG7dv5ypAmrKcIHcnuNtFtsUF7LgOHRNKX/Bocclkhty6zeFH@G6yWtulJauUCySRrDFHIQlsnZSBxpK6VVDKSBPO7OPuESBCcArVRTfIBqfSNz64CtNQN9ARdN8476N/rgcX6ZEuGeBFBqh7EpNY9CIWYf70qesRkMOuwDey0rB4RS5GdLEh91whx2ppkjyY6CYOez15sLd/cJxVtwWSUO/t7WfVp8/uJBS0FhZ26p1D@9HB3t3HzyDAkwcHe08P3j18/@DZE3D3yNniinqJsK@I@oyYaYX9jHzAfeS@0gxDMyaG0TmbTM5eko9Ms2NC0VoTyJszcIlndCBLY22RvRrcuulpH32kuWN6kTff@fKb7/zCm9/7xpvf@/Kb3/v2Tz799pfh/h7c32Dvb/xRpYDPn3z6q3/w5nd/Dxz/K9x/CvcPfvLpb3zMbmr/Idz/Leb2w@COwbGbA1xf@8mn3/zuTz79@m/C/TvB/ZtX71/5wer7219af2O4b/7B9TDf@I9w/yHDFcJ@43eZG76vwP8ug/v6b7759f/E/n8e/ND4e29@/Yf4CCy//Jt//t/efPJfVLX85//@zZe@@eZLn7z50lfffOlfq29@498rcvzxB2@@/cd//Sd/@Nd/8m/o/3v0@Ydv83/zm7/8V//7X/0ff/Unwf0DuP8TmH7wV/8Fmuvf/fF38P/NP/67P/0O/v/X3/@7P/7W333t31HDbzHDP/zOH7Hnjz758o@@9Gs/@uTTNc8vX/v89C3cP/1ncHn7dL4NnrfJ12d1@fRnSs8/hhqLWKAOQM39xTe/8RWovL9OyJsvfw@/xYB7zf97qkJhvsds/z8wqFfzjD4ymOD@1psvfwNJ9L8AieAf0eurkWXJh1m@urAAWX97RaBf/Mmnv/ZdaksY1QadcsJeuqyWM1ug0GxVKkFPHcxGQZCvLGOLEAQxfRW5z5LfV5FvvfnOx2@@@6/ffOe33nzna9g/C/lKdi8rKDdM5QFg4S3gELD4NnAI@CHE38nQEToh8yHYNj4slHO2bdc@/PBDrnMh4Uc/uxfkQ/iRD8OLMC/8KCjwCv3QHb8SIuDefPGijfO/MTdJYcgllb0DL1zZAzEJ6q3MjqSozMu4kDZZKFIDh1w514olXer3t6rwI/CoVrfOs8JOC4Q8GnTOGWGWlADrhkQULZvbymkAKOUZHKnau3I@U9rSNNBcM4g3Q8WcrVD4KuTINBNEOQ3miNEdgKZb1DglbJh/Sr2n3JROJcO/REiZ5Aix2b/GkQyViOiFZ5@FRmoIwoXT0NTIFSCazGISgUqDhAliW8yFTq7TePOgfdCZucwUtG0w4Mg3eN0BYb9ez2DAOksiWFlmGmVCk5LJ1CHfGJqFyXbKiGJ6h2KBkPXMEels1acsYAbxNUJyZDh0OuIVlc@U63chwvr0LkFciJyiffGi3ijXpw1E95pRJzPN3KFpQmT1zLTxGux1ihPCcYm7ryEp5Xom0yhjhJhJVjyoYGMhFWjmaN5xZpeVAbxxedXOLiG3eKXMs/mTDSQYg8ZnZgGNgAAO/q3MVpAd@g@N9N6iBN@gUQWxEOa/Q8XgHSYZIwDgFQRRFAncuGhhh@yC95ShytBo4ZVhGDK0RtAaEDkQShMuQ8uXEQjiB2d6DCxR1XwNNIsaQSdX5/DUOLoSRuY2p7jK6ZwEUrAcHIU65zSAycs57vxCC1ZBbWpkDk5FDiFonPWtz3xhYpFYm5ubXKLB5/jHdN43I0nEPanStWzQcqmOVCV8scKjs0EX9jHiPcRV5FmOmmuYTfLm4@8m8nIpwW0m6bHThEVEbmXYvbu7RW4BWek75jalS8aETM7JOwlGxu1Mhlch0oYDti1KwgzFxj0niTr@wT1BKxZJkCeaa3pZLktZYhZeYj2B3uTx48dBeqnD8zqXgRan5hS045zfZDKB4EYP59ezWVHMitls8BbpmzqIgUGkvsFb3ETSk7gup5TKeN6srQ@RLtzr16@hbnBIi@ohKNfMSOpqvkw9Ca0GU1zMpY2yHNsFwrJm4ZpRNV/h2EgEUYp5QlK0RsCVJrg4MgVVO82xFVaseoVXKqmWQV1GSCgxMQVgDE1RQZ7EVqHSb4FIobRkhZTFrTi@yMa0ceI/Wv7J0pcqF9Kh5/5jsv/44cODR8fjdptwBj3f2OiMXUc3PC@FfnuP7rLqq1aK6USziXk/rqrII7mDqozVOHN49@jwaZUwigVFl6L5qNE584AuFYVLjMcfbCdcHFd3DR6P7XL4p/isLkiRUivAv9OJBpfQDVS4oJ7iH@4aOTIGWH0feoM7zpSk5CzPZ5UiqsNpnAKG5Py8MyG4@STbqQK4A67UEyG/mPLGuRCbWUKHBjlSOWYQFGoguUo5NJSYQSkVEeAxO/cuxzWeHhwD5uPHRFFlkRw5XRMS1fiQTEWaziNnZDhZYU5DI0c6NkcOQlh1y7AH/nATzxLmWzIfI9BmU87iT83l4Knki1mlUGpvbFjnAuJp0SpzjusQ52A9F5Am78BFuHc48g44wSXMCeeM8XMoNoB/@LjGKi9@40tSkPqnvssrBeALaQ7nIgJ83Dh@1YDo0M6WJ/W4xMYXv@iTRuPg0V3h8B4OOkyHJFzEKJg9cSjSitObuAb1HRDSM9838YQ3sWd6Y0ubQSMGem01gCA@Tq4m5vN5H3Ae3iNqQ6VWFraHz7lOXbpgnk81jgCD7nOJ2@E4C1e6Xa3WXyv5EqStWn2dU1UOHLgtkCrM/gbUNrogZUtiP96u5xU5o4SzGCTN83zNg0TlcmVpi0soPA@vXC7H0QZEuKrBEbpM6bVcrwsBj88rdJUSh6cNaNO6Gl0B7PTWAjYnM1j0AQ8y8F0ih34l5hfYwm4BsoLrdumhtrWAo8i3b@dwtCmXl6O8E0oaMoci3czlc1hI4Aau7US@FEyPQf7aCc4yfNKrgznRwgyzxqwkeII25H@5sswlmglo2lyz3az/f/9rN7n29F/uH8jSbNa5KXDI@B04Iwx9k6Ufxz10Hi/@jx@P4tZr/6PHzsPHzsiBP/SED5GB1xb/Wm3Jev0/4JzIlGogCnO@MYXqBL@8XADrP3z747//9f/89//2qyJegS1y@Idvf4u5/86v4vNb3/77b/3C33/r31KXX/n73/k3gdc//M7vk7vQxmevNOg/uTdf/@TNp3/05vs/ePPJb7/5/p@gNf7/9D8EXp98a@EIZnS59P8W@Ztf@T//9re/@tc/@Phvv/WDv/2tP/7Rx19Xy8qPPv6lv/2tH/z1n36NgP3HP/zKjz7@2t/80ic/@vgXAS7@//EPvxp6fSlyBDO4XP2DO@Dl/kVdwO1oi2YT09vBhp8Nuoi8qVTy7QPgGE3S3g73Am0A9Db7dIngJix1Hstb8k3mxjc8w@qLuDS7zm@PGzlZ5beDDcUb5H3DRo4chG/06j1Hp8ep13qiicfa45c5LFw@z9ccG7fxq4ezv9Btp88H9TP6VXfNqA9E3BjGtTULgned3kz0/BnIW7pjOW49CbpnEkTW903HopUGzHs9x0Zx0K4boJvgiPtOLpevQv7EsTPeUQslgQhNRQYZDm@lnO1Br@LuQGdWVbMbxk6pVO2JumVo7k6hWkBvPZqz3ynI1YH44cMH931/fATih@H5O/kKBMDN1XAbpJ1ytVCAhszzmSaNsY3nRLPeWtjYgN7N0HoCvHFK3xPUcrtK46/Xk8mdnKIKSjUnl7kgswuC2TVbyCvFHbnqx8lIDizTdtwsz@FxtlEpYAEOlUZezm9L8AZ9W8L1BSCbNMieMTBQiKAlp2xLY6wTYARQDYxdMBa2pS4YTTBWtiUTjJNGTpG3pQmrGlgExOzVISLMTgbTmsU6kh0q50EXXbUd25hz1ayWNc9pcVX7/f586zyzsHDaucBsUJBzQct2zyNrTYjBVckkK5gLT3DR@lAvzoM1FFVeLZT5WrO2sJeKfK0953ZHRs/U8Pzxlnx@NVQRRCeGNQERtQg3r7qO41e7Rt9xjQVgTimGgCxBVwHy/DyKriVjjOdXoyvGgKbnV7HkC/w8ChUmi5vPoWSR6Ej@xPPnXGLr6P1cowFV6zxfUvOFfEHNFYuFkgriXiVfLJShZOWiXFBVaN/5SrlSmkPDkqTXCXrWHtk/DxtclZ4wkNKqbB/NZpukXz8yrfNyTmAcIpWugXyQeM0lbh29rzYa68ejUiA6v68KjXquUAFTDk1qjkoTqiqoOSGnCEoO/zcYVPy/PbwKfxWfECqncse4u84jkFpBYLfJA9ycw3fIsePQL3juGPoaiP2hRnfy2Xcdz/tHwNzR7BPmdddkW9pGXvc1PJPOG5n@cA3Es/EIN@Yx3H82DAejLiQQGTIDuAMP13KcVQAl8uzJmlw@jDaRB2KwXeQB/Ojw3fvHsffxwd7@fa5I7jx@dPfSqxAAFciDg3vHkbXEfMOghQjFzx88eHDZGrzyj58d9SeOizd37/Gz/OIROeGHT1wermWgyJkiCR5oRaEHZXOyAUpyaFA4/Obqdr5CbgfGQnFhlNH4Afuqy/Siz7LYh4FV7jj81EsjyKW7BtHZ/ks4ekj3Rgz0eKVU4bgxsZ0zUpJJz7EszSVOv78BjkPNI13DQLXUsrAmYtRnjmv1zsyesQHCIsRRUfAQc0wEdx@QjCY6/aIf1ALcabeHR97j/HvXmhhkMiZrHeGFTmh0zcEQhIEzJwTguppG4P6sF4Q34pd/vYPP4qBuV3ysq@Bcgtt7jOMNlQTP7/P8fc3Xaq5Rek4aB1OoqdBuNHeWLWdzvF/gq/YA52stz@81tyag5Wxs5Mvkb377ez/@s2@pLXlfxnHovDrT6opU69aJUrxo7OSdXVSFULfe6hiJ8qBe9QpFZQf707qc2U043n2jXON5zc4CB616OKpwz3F7VXJgm8A/7sHF89hn6ifPcVyyVbNBU6ZaLaEVr0pltruOq2u4chg1UUL1ykAhFek4iFopF8qVnFrOlivlfEEpFgpZRc0qpXKpAomTlbJSLBcqSracr4Csla@Ab6FSCtRZSdoiexYOX2WZyiptVQG9reMB3tt0SEUcNrgEW9xBXqW0NElokX1CeAPC8GTPHhgW4MCRMJ9@drhl1qE7JopMciUCmDWik8S9e/syZvsOWnDJ277M8z20FMqyXLrD8wb12S@jOMk7LEwZ90zkfWaR5TtQohOGAI8b4PkhWg6KOJXB8yZa9vcYeftoUTE8gJ0wH2axQksJwGy0gH5NEbyMsAHYHosnTxN6gBaMEn3uMZ998OP5d8PkoM8RA2MI7oc53dvj@UNm2dtDn32a7QJL6OfRskcvnnfBAs2N5wdgGLjQ0KGigBEbHc/rYNJnGrjhoem4I73tazw/Y@RBAvH8lEJr@gnPd0J3jOb9IDUFpG6VWhSW611qqeCP59Uw0QiWiyw5ns9Hljzk7f7997Wh3zMG7Jq57K1DTu/fz2nmdHJwr/vuu93BoOvO9g7ePUKv/f37INvMJm530A0CdjtwORBq/76qnYxmly/I9WGnU9WslV6f73Tymn3JqzPrGJhCCPUSUhZcA4xo1NkHr/37nV1t1WIdirCD/GYE7y5ed0bwvqN1mVd4US/6nna7fA2aAWgerRSHyhKut8HmeQL8286ONN11amif1olMVzXPmkW5XaMeZATajlybo38/hU8NR5vT57PmtC6369N6KVgs20/xralaMPnsxmhHqRSqG9qOouYz0yp@Me30kyQpKDskpdzeekVSj9I7Kug8G3xrZ0fgm0p7p1h6jgyuio8dVSlX87JK0syaK1UhjJyUCcFHullq75QK1UXgUimjSWq1VAJREOjjg0DRxfHdDkmlzgztJJ3GpNMBQsgPzTiZ0UybtX5qmp3WWSLJLF2b1pUa25aZyJewpVI9PANgouNmDYQhHQDCKSg9uNArxSuVMg9pkKRUGpjRfD5nxDnPy@X5@bl3ft6aR6xSAtNiiPaDLxyfHB9/CNwKJJZZlgqljWBw84lrIM@rBdZ37@@Lh49DG27vL95DYdlxxX3kcUs@TGoOnY5BBRLvQzcPOm/oBmF817HEA7oiGiTu0CPcDkMMttoVj@8v4Xk6dM5YzBDIq9H9GvFbdTz9wOwRrd4Ak9YjKZoqoqXPqIDRaTTqnfrIGI39GWQxDPV5Qo8GWKA59Fja6ektuPUdDX7ed51R4NGpy3Po9aaJqSCQPZD/Jm4WMHbqRFBejJzeCzWj13p4/MGd@h1EU@vAuwtau@G6jsuD0snX@jt2fWJ7Wt94Yrj4Af7h400QfHD/ilSfGOlN0jpA6H3Ul@ZCwyX2Io2PJqOUJjS66WUnnBCIHJBMqS@E2T/HAXFIOc/Pa/06ST0H0JdgdzdJqifeSe/ka0CxO6STBif5Rf9Fn6ikmK9RtSiFuKAJUkohBbR0vfF5kNcY6hNSrUJqgiI/AawYGSCG0qA@Wnpszmt63SIpgUzTlEb52qDexOAX@NgWQMgQhOZFG8fzP0Bd4eUEOs8GNPfaLKHVvUmXHqBD5K6iysXaFNyUUr42hPLWnk9rbn08cY2aBdZgBoDQHGs1oC2QENC8uki9@crH6W2hUGduNYrqAoWWjtipT2s2bskJNaWeq4NHppmXs4UyyDOFUhZECLWYVYrZXDafFUroCvJDtpAFR1DLQEBKWSmeED4rT2VRySqGkk3JL8zei3T2JCUDHSjx0lnfObAnI4IuUGRYW6kd3lo6o24BiXoO0bYFWnmBydQwX0D7IRmb2SHFdGRoFguQFkhuK2VtphBo83gyPmi2q9WD6fgL4JUSXu4UMyU58yqdrqU20nXPeElnS@6YUEE0IC5yJpr98QbU6WCWhHiTURNKHUxKSa02m13Ma0nO5uQcZNPsXAy2@QbfzsobRQXKbE7H0BTCOEt8YgAkJ27hNu6g3mAZUIZKRa1xIo7HJ8gdd0JnKnJlVahIha2CzGYHGApuHLBIpC1Jtfjgc4pkKpksqcnkQslOJ2s4DbvBL@bFqOpNl8KmksCySfK2Wiju8CAA8lW@ovIAtuC4mEoihynfIvua4WkuzqBwOHBD8qC6n3Pz8/l2g5uK3MHItEwtS2xTx5PoTP1E5FCWzZKuOSB9zce2LHJ7kNvDqsg9BT3QoKbmAZ4iQFh4uvUEBmsHCKt0dskfzoYGKEciN6OTbb541RVKieA7jGoZgnyOe4o7F2yrz/FXev5w7zH@7u0m8PsFsvs58KuAe/n5w2ePnz2@R79OX3w@@lmuXY5I9COFqdipJWp0VBxXIEA0TLp/@2sXZ5@JtIEfYJOMKIgN@mn/LoulFWwyI20Q8lm/oshsN56zdwu/yQPUHN3CvEnadHWzYaIaT97XQKDcIUkocs0dNVU1126qJRBLoOtqygxUVZUapKKToF@TNqB@T88h0duZBn7A/3kym2kZIcz6bdIYZDZldZY47fDFSo5@bd5pKPIJ2Uje3sJzzQWSOD3ZaKhbmeSTai6TvJvM5ROnqdZmI6PMkhLZyqizPq7VwjU/UhLgVGPrVm4r@SxTLQ@yVSWDTxWe1SQRNhK7nexuuuJxtCaTxBKBNyp79b3B0V4waUH29htldRZsPJB43uHLpSCJrU0gmZp5vrsUvgGy0HOcurxUbuRnuHZx8XaylkycJ0kiOU/Om8k2l9ilWySobIsEkog2ScAVV8Gsfy5fJOkESQe2UiXhpdJ0FUQw7f655G4iibPbxPNeQ6WmZUGbdvjB@edfqMBoErYTOjgTH8dpQZQqFHDuNiG9GHtfVMu5h4eP7bvuPYNLtDYuNhyclyc1nqHkyWv7vS8QMoYSS5JWPTGt54PZT6XREJRtFbeWKpEqCAF9pSjIFw3GzRrUo6iCz5uv/GZ@ul0GuyorYFfVQkZtNJQtEEMT4zefft93Z@T84P29BySJc6k//rPvqqUf/9nv0@XgyTmdX1VzpQRAolEplhLn5@PzcxAC58yvkGgnriyRawOZJEWrlLZEqAtSWQNDR0owkoK4XFLSCU9IBB8DFAtCKqVIanorV5bT4HMRbN@TUuUyWMNFDtSJLxb4dOLgyCyoyu72DuRsJ5dXaxtQrEq08wWJftuGV0lwifLDFxeEgEVv9AYDU6UmSQra0WuBbL8WtuENJfxa2CAv6g1c56fgphnhlPkWfnqPC1iSjYy0lSSga5NGc16btzN02p2OhDzfsluXiNHawA84l522bPgZWx79GQa1UgcPrKHN2PrI41NbaUnq9Wi/g0seBKGRYK2uY5BCA@rLlgSp3AqnydlPEFrpN1/5DVUt/vjPfuWic9H5UFXVSqVSVNTET3@6PbEnntFr/BQCPgk3SoNKpJs9rKzHzolhe2I05kA7O9PG08VMOxqrIGyPNjMIFRlEnecSExv1MQYfjlzgGAUBmdQc2EaPjlhwpyhR02LtsK3JeikKtkVAIclSfY7uhZSucVyo6zB9zR3oWYqDbOG2ws12mjvn3kEvkM8I6Hw17p0FKnAYgUTm6B3Pmrhj@uFrioZT2llyG4JADO/gtm8bAJ0mQb8tACeGvvpKUJZkj1KNytwE99jGTeRAHOHegSDBJuzWjIw11zMopGmDrCAiCE0n9eg1Ie42xG2xAB3qmqK5ZwBZwlLHAtmgxnHvgHxJqWCC2EnMbQCoAU95BwgAeUgFiM022Sa5NDk3M5naYoe6Oe5Mgp@AauEWahwGQ2w9IFMUuIZw4ATqI57oi/UiKGHgezHHEAnDwVaw1UEBxeDUhgK9CdVh@taoANfZEEuIZo3cvr1IVb1u9tKE5gjxn5hjHL@l5WCvTisgCzX5W8BSQaTKZLCw31mudkDxDE0u1DqBbfpXiwUlPFrnHAf/t660WCMvFRX1qGEGgvJirUIHkkFgJDsrQ51s14miltIkSrwOaddpougGO9HwRGt6S1Q/DD3nkMKfJsJDtYBZHcfHxIN6e9ewLkYXEcE9AkrYhO4V6Q81xgx6hmWOzOBgemR6h34YOgoFWTEtCt03XVCF6UK5cOe5VE5JY7DFTn00HfRzNzVP8KOzQhpfNBRCE3hruBNaEM8GFV91BwrUGzs23TrNR9aEn/1BjQAeBRE8cnyDJXtin@EJeEHZ0MDxFEEuQdPBmo8pplvBObbhsbC44qzrGtpJSJssMQYi0Uc9olZIilY0Gxdf2BG6NA1EE9wFDQpp3LWMESTpqWHQ78@9qiQNQPCbdHEqW3poQr0a3jOh@7E96S4jsHRmnpjSMe5ALTh9/EydIgcsICti82Nr1kDZnFg9YjnOCbHME4NNdaTi29Dh4RvFLCg/WaDs4gbCVlHsVXNZHAhTsgwK7hK8SsxYzsbCbqRm6avvnLKR6mCJXtAezIRSsYxTzY7Rl14XXDCY4s08ju66VyeoPKTALkYsF1om28AqiTtYJdMi0L6XSnO0fD0IgiFFnEIbp/gEnxa9sWX61MiNXeOU4GAIh30MME29EyQBWzHk9h3aAdC2By0Ld8Lz3SqUXAZS4vZSOjS9gMHb5BbJqRwCQswIyhIAOLDo68vYwQ@CYj48vwcFI9J5I@Qr0DpHPfDDnbaC6ofhw9qNZrov4aJ6k40AHXY6NK46Yc0itBRiFmwdWJ9p1jfAswgpXJGSjRSfAbQZPs0z1FH4y8FZbecoL6mSq5iyBDEEpAYsVFTQkOXQ/WwXR9Xh2o87msfOM8FaD5X@7OxMpJs@TlxTNDw8vs1zbM2SxgMTxGFH8o3RODgo29SlcYh3YRLYqY3ieDjemaJQW6/cnrE3x/W9erAENZXse0nsHE/xdLLB6BT1K0hw36MV6p5JTzbUU8GKWFb/1Hb2PKx/Vax/Qjk5RySEIJppdpbVs4As29VPsv2zXi3wOKUNEpBDKRqhI27F6oaWkReazHE/gnB85KORV9c6oUsMABPPZgwWUbMchpCz0BrYxyauXLeNM7LnutosRf3TCI0VODWjYg@ZQbdPfcCIW7yfs31BzWlz1l4KPo2CQ6cWLQQCRp7CnutapGyTWPSfMv8p@E@Z/3QRaRhtc9pmIhk6zTE7WOtxCX4IiWhmIcycbai68KGYQQ4nCkOBkLMlN1yqq9dp6JDezAblWA8rBtSJMRDcSEnN561mq217xtlWOyMNoLLzlBBQ4oC62aY0PetFZqS@dWqNHW/JCboPKt4E6UYnfRjUBlZXMI9RAdGKwehl4iaYg1GwQIkJBEGGAQPKYeCJosGenzLTtWhXYuoJFafJL2jMEtYMEtOm0lfgFbiBuMRIzwgbR9SOIUL3KEuQTPAhYcthh3WG3OED1wGYEFag5wsCi5yRZDsJlLzUVBivqdFCiqVKEMJkAtlRXK1fzkroD0XRvOQVy@Y8KP948jc@c/L70C5Wp55WWNZh1Lh4U8H19iBCBM2FUpU06rFyhRRIW5pluNBzHTD5NOitIZotKVQzWDyYBe/M9PVhKlb4epqVD932gLf5alQVZvU6ZHFWZ82StYuQpIzgUTAvCDYLK0IQnjEQwCGvDGYEwabxYNN6nTEOMl0T7CyWyClN5JQFYdD/b3vfup42siz6O3qKDk4GZIubYzsZfJmFASes5ZhswMnkYA9LBoGZAcQgbMNkvL/9EOc9zqvs1zhPcU5duqWWEDZJ5rLX@mavPbGQuqurq6u7q6qrqucrkLyU1UB7qqrtBYfnEqRTjARIALw8b6MgBk0SwrNvHfTq@PFmNEGtSrUZrDnEBZKHUMRGPutcxrbe0pDWFq0IAGTEJQBdvve7YEQXvHza/@WvUUxKtUbxL8kGvFYAg9ESvG@wDuQzGenAIPAntmgfgLmb2GoZiTwdFeD/cvxfwlIv1X/55Ze5cMl8@GXOivzvd3l5iZTVJqgmfeRzO7ggG4GlQjdZvHVBGwzsEJrThPYKD4vC72ABGFMx1uBGCCVFituD5gWyL/AUZ/bAjyRFBSsnLFFSH@OFxkqce5RMmRoRlGfrDvSMi3HC3NfyuSsrQ7AxCnFSPa2ITQr66JHgrITmxDTBUgqj8XQwfggBOt0jyRsnEVktnnsF@A9wsBRIIBPZL1JEG/NR3IgiVze9FqVPkhOB@FSk8jo2iGAPlOMxHq9bieeeSFjfQEUTGbdSOzGNcGJ0eUwSqg/IeZNxCmpZiXQmQVXhHSyt@M4Mg@DRxPcKYUAZZVOliKFCgZeuZeiCEGcOXRn3HVLM7Gz@VW7vW4N6N7Zm1qj17aW12TlMCFiC7PHIu5nedX/qu9e3PTEUkx@v5p3FLz8LsbuDoapi@xsORczvHWYpdOqlwCjWb3OU0l4i@B2FVWJK6owyaScFJbNn//6nghLrC/JVKKBMGOFSsTlSXIhGhdnhqLV3eTiGRXjUGl/uo1ljtnU428pvpfDFN3kTM@xgzVSnNbsEutxrs2jTeG2DVkO3YBavPDr8hD3NCJkLZrBDengKS4cXeNnLcACCPjHTHSmkMk4OlBVg2ACifpW1Ue2hZk/lLXyS6j1UyogaQr4boFDif/DwSjiPdlg8Yp1hhnYAicddIGFQgnTYZV9ss9LuCOwRloJdu68jgSOO5hic/n7a9YwhU9Ab3FXqCxrH8NZjgYornvrDTl0wjP@4GXR@Kr0W27ncy3zuRV4jGV51iwjmMi92gu0KiKQ@bKObz25@xzBK7mTBbnywmSOsnTQCtMQpKsfvQS9zbp3x2DGKwyH7@3l4U4AzvXW6GcOoO11yJb26IYqgGneD5AKt1r2Zdji9/NVgbE8XyBd49wUlpIfJj3/RT3EEqk5P3iVnGWgFAYVsNJixrcS9HeA1Dr7lp@cOh@4dEqyDRhemB1YaObDHGZumCKOExFK4kL4/uvFmOKXRaowA7Su8ibbjk2EMm18HRoZMGMYQQJHhTmts3I1gAu11hjaqWpk4BKAhjQIKAeha96bjPIiDQUh8Jg5CdkxFWNhqZLLu1HBproxsVG1BrgsITKNC1TTcYYCbb6oN0aidND8U6xUBz@/qtffVcqUsjj@K5puKKNXefSQnXfGmdlqu1BsCgzpLtbNmvXp83qzBi0SxATUT9MEonn0Ule/f1SuNhqjVRfXtu9MqQAPw9eJZs1ppWKJ6Vjo9L1fPXlsCIIizWlOcVt9Wm1CsWbOoVVXNCOqJ2ol4W6mX3sDP4nH1tNr8SC2eVJtn2NgJtFYU74r1ZrV0flqsi3fn9Xe1RkVgx4xytVE6LVbfVsoZaB/aFJX3lbOmaLwpnp5GOlr7cFapI/KhXh5XAMviMWyP2BL1s1ytV0pN7FDwVALiAYKnlmi8q5Sq@FD5vgLdKdY/WhJoo/If51AIPopy8W3xNXTOSD1CFRiX0nm9gidRSInG@XGjWW2eNyvida1WJlo3KvX31VKlsS@M01qDCHbeqFjQRrNITQMMoBZ8h@fj80aV6FY9a1bq9fN3zWrtzIRB/lDBWzZKRahaJgLXzri3QKRa/SNCRTrQAFjiw5sKvK8jTYlaRaRCA6hWaurFoEEgYlPvpjirvD6tvq6clSr4uYZgPlQbFRMGrNrAAgAT2/1QhEbPqdc4ToAXPwKzGopzLRpOUT0RxfL7KmIuSwMHNKqSW4hspTeS5hl0sNUEtAHeYOfYI11o6y2/unXQKWxZ2ouX//zzp1KtXBEJdW6YCD6cw67zKnIwpX@Dncb/CD9DBwBd5@qm38YrTlBi96uxUDXy@hbmNDAxmvrCeOCsWspuVGFjo91@X2wX668b7bZprVMzhMZjNSgxJwhrD5QyZR8xRAxtaChUFgpM94MQoY6@QXGw50wtwY7IVJKp/w1trmN7BLpiNtt1ZDU0hSBgJZbCHjx1RwKAdXFpJCssxn8HTZLUQ78Hkh2oYkqBz3Ta8Bp7zoVcD/4Z/xr84M1BewGrM4vS2WzfmTEaoKCqZrgRMjDRP9K@A9oXSfKe4/zUT@X05pxx18zgfUDoISnrUNmZMxz2U@Yj1a@cfqR6OlqfkEWjpspf63GwAWsXyJh8DiZJJuS4ZKbUsxT@057RH1NhwxY0NJRQU2SClwpR6huu3spdIlnZUAgSNQ8yynxvi99XP6CSm9ve2Y@8f@O/57mFToPoXwobXovqXdKfN5dcACYYWTaBJANpb8xmtToglpFA6Re@g4LXWIjvM8K9@tqhfR1IAoLsDV5Ip9WH3Xg6mOvYwzr8ul58e3x@cgJLJ2K782r35d6@4R9ifm/x34/YDnl40hnuBPZxkNPokzZLSiD40EzR3PED9icGzmaxIAZ3qEGjl2g18y8NYiGBs0CQLHXwgi5N9TD0xAYlyhnTRUdkznxqKH6NnZmSAVKhrprYm5E9JxHfBlmJeEAemg4XNGpz/Adh@9NfTXG/Q5KBJIuRzytwrvGE170EVqKTtp57M@ZjECySSSg@5kNxnwZ4C5LIF@QxIv2SvK2NIgi2ONA4X2nYqSYg8TSKhZB6KHl3QxPvyGorlUs6i4U330t@g8eP0l2AnAdsb1acNYCMJ35N1IEDRVd2uiUhX2KwHR5Rq5YOBFoQTIkUzT2pqvpmVm02ECoYqorWqTDgfd8qG20SFeHk35KgbzOnoikU4exLjpW/gXPjuiOh7CtrrPytbHyCYfkmY6band@GoYp89K2CipwhMn0VPQj@n0iTGPgHoHEC9IBamkvFWpQkqEwrUF@JKIM7ZcTQLCcBNfVXHwMw9/rAXPsdk5ahObkSIAnk6CzUi4/kRNJLxRAAmdxEzwJt/nZdh@93vLZBdfpbwpTV0QYz7owmKSH3CrVVLMFN711aJHZZym6DP0xhkmFWaA2eQlXxN1bcrmjWg8oUUeXFcy/B4ExlTc1u4nlGMOGJS5EieTXZA87KyVmm1gF5cKVtOF3//AnE0vuVFsFNoTkchdZ@aVVThALQR4jPcj8p6tAVnaHrORH/FU7J3ySfAvTet@RVddIBAD0N0MUJ4TzvCnkLnDO7ww1iyNDJ8SGAJlLPyfcCG@FjiUBwUMutmQHS0rZ652M/J@zvNOzPxxxjQj8LQpXIsI@JxHCM1/gBz9DFwOKtvQCUh@t1m1ksu9lwLXHnUCQPmyVkfQzC7LjuFERHG/sNOFqDhZkRH6TRwRl7N1PpDQL72WAqLRJK6IdmZnSjOtECtxmO3SDUvAHIDTO0uSB/UJdGjj2WDiKDeXpPpIB5FY8eIQuTW8t8Ky9SB8GXA6AJOXkREQ/EHqYYo1JMUOmA5RAFB56vXMAscbmdA5ELpt@dO/0J934UgcZdp@v7eWkg4YUapOqYPGY6M@76xPXIogFDgRYQnxJ5NqRd2Z2f7lDyhj36pWQnENDxVSLwNUJPMOrJ57fjM6mEig0FjCtbB@bbS8NgIpW2paOV73qV394lVOIUrvuVyhj5XoVN4iJxMfaXlIK8a/O5Eh3xiddN/@kjPvFda87hcw9nD7xB@7kUQRFhlFnRZru8zhF@eF7xYeBMu7pNFCSZrj1B8xupPu6YeFGZDqUTRceeec4CNIBOdjDPEox26u/u9bhdcod2f@AObNDTMLxizisePi7oEQesP3XvPIov5gxCWqHuIngma7g81Mbf0mMHfwYHnd7MmaT0I5DZdFHEDBSoxdAxPp61@vsV8fckeuLs19nZDSr5deS13TfeNeim@yvrvsjHVebTAgQgF7ijyOkMHZM76PN4qFpyJyntuEMVuHqogIbjlUgLW/t8vxLjb4FEdMAbwlghs3TkoXcCNbOVGLe6c6tLHh1TdwbrVtnBuFUvRa8tG9NXwiryHZ5CFET@VU6rSrkhu3P06sCHxWpyb7/8k7EHBL4C/fyLOG6JYwRa4npyNsCaTMqE9NkCXMideUBrNK3EsIoN@rALDUNA2/Mo1PDnxSpq0KkiCEXSaWGJK3FGpkDxwTQYqTYsOe0F3UidFEmTHAVQBCnOUrnVDOvozKr71@jt4BE3h9llcGEqScgpDelVpOoAlTAhXgjm5EZHmT1UH58x29vrjlqEgIeSgCEctEyRqYSSXNATW11fjsda7hQW40SEevJUMunN3ElyTeqtXDtiz7njaN0xVxHpU4TZDmGz3OwSaQ8X@LjYN6L4RJgmTDE6xQYeQvWVnn02jxJxftjG@XbYXjxCh1U0C85k/U3FH@8uz33cFG8xtFRtNP6UItzR5Wvff99qQ8fbq1cQCZPVqzatGG1cMtoLftRARcjkU2l9ChH3Sdwj9OgC5bDdLtBOH5@VRI0ewCsHMvUp5DKE9EQ3eHvk4Lo06WWgIylTnU/5i5QvcM6tBR3l5dNX6LKJHxggSsVOOrBDsQU3GKwIH1GsRS/VRrfAPK5E8HTEPrvK80ki6hOMYhykcYfde1vtRTp/uc@Q5j4k0Cr4WuwHIMlXWKzVnhOUJVLAFI8hhd@jpbXpev1efW1foBxA4Nr02bvBI3iQprAzeA975xr@0T@15ygDB03JmqEZFZ4IbVoaYC6AltIfOqyuovQ3mDLHw0NKTiNQIPh1Cv9syRroHL2X86mNVebdBRYxJbl5tpmY3oyqBAzFv5H8ciqyqEuKKwBwGGOof5gHCOgkRtjjocDQ6c1CnBdCVI4RVDzM47SEl@RjFviQxHxHosoCO7taiVxciW91GOlYICBYxJcJEAGZJb5IAAU2ulhctBIv4/sTlACBWPE@UxyGQo5KmIb@yDEBKfVdzgxWlFZeWDnJwfRxZ9cMffT5m75@m9O@5qJfgT4@hq10Pvr1VS70NdTs9na4aqgm0MPUWw19BFKYOsL@qvB1/2eQS6DmQK4k3ANNyQhJGdL3C1MTgpYJelvmR08coInjSMkYCh4dxqXzpCoq9avNAWshF/eH3dlFko4M0BP@q3urYjYUJjLyInkxJkd7Nu6yQkgSawK3euwWarrkTYGGE/I4Af1W6bRuT7xvnpzoSrC4WihHo5Ez3c3lcsjEV3oogfLbQlPSwM2GS2d7N8NhdnL39@n7qyyt/Zgxeui5BaVBOzAkMCm8jDvtc5wN4gBFsXQaCDxybx3U9W96PT2gBU8ocfBg2Lgk@4p1BW1AA9/p5X2TA@xPgg32n9hB7N8/hT/77mwWNCUUdQwFtYF6F7cJdXoG5MEXPfT98k@qCBguzMqbCfYt8/DoE@4gGCdGg0XOoCaahST7J944w6FriQ@YoexpgiwqkQonJ3qFHBfBE0YkCroYDYHDLOHcDobB@ZSHRXReR3BqY1JRO8rLHiMN6k6/Mp@kEq0fErCtQJe3sJtb6O1riUQ/YUrX@zXAMh8C2muVHtmTVIfoFC0MW72cwcETYPQib8XqPqEiJtnEJM0eL41EjUc386M7GKeg6ybJAioygIaXerKiuE/cxMU830Ma5hiGxIlucFurxv3@1y2NX7cs3s56vfVWRQqq4IH9rBWR48q@bkGkMwCagXL6AT0xuvIfaZjWJ5FAKBZwMPRped3BCm2sYBjPO4c/36WKxaJ4NtnaEsXiMTxgop/joijji@NjUcYsKvj7m8Pt3d19XnPL5id4eaxe3otjgMH3xHaup2X4Cd8OMcANtnvSIp9lD59Z@8/ahwdH@162VTy@zGb78MT3JWWL8gdepJQ9ph@tH/xCmUwm@6zz6dk39/v4u1W@TD67aj2bXCb7@8hlQIbizcytztJ24D6amV4ZG7wLaG/Jj1Tp2R5maJVVhUqPMLKnP8HqUhAbHS@7Id96HIdLa@xGx9HeO2NMhAIqvArhiKryBobIj@wFmuNhdDoOOuDBfgOUBFzQD5Tr89mKMtyPXa2Af6qyQQhImfXWAdB4wrGATnLDGD@QHow9Z4wW8FuSebl7hmHD38GsLfk3@4O892DzIiU2c2LTEpuJBP3BOxA2L8xn2QHerMHF/NsRgqMFdDMU3oAEPdIfKHIxQm7DeEYBkAhJhUNT4fHN6AqNz0r7w/BJGb7u9Y0ndKkjm0jokAmrbHx6Nr6HYfkEJe4TxhMKZ8xj7g8WFNpSi6HGtBMVf3xRBLI9dgQIWh4xQQouNIknfVCZz/yy6o0ca4NiMwkwkrX@@oTmPb6AvegZxXTmI7oUBo1S8CO/xb1xn4N3CW38wu0HCNCBCquTOQobSW4k8awDIyiDXlI3BcV46v2TzMe@DgtnhhWD5v9TaExAn57ohHs2pnd0jkkfmf6JgX@8ojWV4LIUbc8nM4ZWZXQznA0mQ3nmRSTCkfNbu@eZhCNKgBgOR1AXlmcYGQow88GdQ2HI@rBw6PFCdF3sOs8EmX4Vp4OZ4ZMjjQjZH1Iwt3@NzG0zO0BMFDswDxBSvitfzx4MPST5TOVx7dvTK8y1QOmaxWDG52Zkz8O8OhGM3Z6PdIYgk8t5MJ@hKxuTqd0f2ZbYOHObU3tRhW0LJJ9ZJ2NCD8fJGSGBk082Hdc9hTD3SA4JUcTvCnkOYfT2cCGDzXlscTRoMGhI1VSQCRpwEoTYiSjp/BoaqwgdA67@jEHQUV5avP3TSLnE0sqLnkYSUtAF@Iem2dLUMVQL@tzxJ07CYFT9mal4QVa6wY12RAe/sJIPXdh7ZdtU05HngwKWS2wfd6e@M7ZDm9NkaBicmORZdl/wvojzmRJ7sDeSvLEn/zIf5A9ArECO/CGU4EZmunB7LLMZT1KpJxeeDI7f0PcRFJ4zvi9@1kZWlWflFA4@oqR85@MBL5aRHWrAtAcmzIgqef4DhN7Q7gN@izt7gax4sZH67mnWbP1wMb7cTF2Mf734xSRM5JKsdtm02JCH2WrFknMFdsasFfqpvNI8wTfKi4txuMDFmNy6@PRekgAQyaZaP2Qvf80CQhcbprmZvdhggoSGDDHJPtxeFsFnl9DcCGOR3TCemJumGvzUd3lTwN5Kf3EM@YXJfwELpVSSmR70nGkPQFEMEF0pgIpd9tV2bmc7vwOaUN@Zp6fODe63ae/mypmDKOGhOgtbz8UvIW4IEeJ@7tn78HIO/Rz0x5gamkbUkwkt5BIqpzm1Y/hsBXUyzBNQHqicQhJgiIvpl7Hx8BEVfksAy6mylNGCXQc17kvh/um5I2zH9nBdi0aHMEeilwH7iJAJNY2QJeOt5FBTTZckBZtlROnagUFGIDC82Q1ttxi747QU1sxMch@FaIyaGWJu3@gcXZqioRn6TApTyacif/Tdy//@37WfN2YbR9vZD1P4O9v4eWPv1QY/wgP8eqF@3W4cbRxgsb37jUUWdGB4fPnf/wfqH/0d4OCXxQH8c7SrYO0tNo7Sh1Tl142jPXjIb29Du//3v/4L@vCMNTbMbPOsbQlCbF9RpGSPiXfhu6hiL1ktTQbLSh4XFoTBHoagm8MPdIyab7/KkZluQ3pV3KL7z6A38/1R5BZPjlkzchViS4bypwDJiCscYgNpBqlcKHpC891QbhvIvAGa4p/PM3seaAD/lO4cfpO@68ZzD12GnrFaBAOY4hZBn@eHo9x3Cd@9o5BQPiX7SoRE1U6uta9e7AM7vHOd2aAT9pJQ03XUse@cqwzyYcbp3oBONfaG7o/T7C2w5Ci//SrbQ@N@lvy4sxOClJ4sMr@AICizkYBiSE6nlpjCCLgj@AvPmKMEBPoT/0xKZecAKXvidNiGFc7wBEUazXKlXrf4eBi7kwlE6RT9CwI85iGRaTW0yPOLMdSs1QsiseUX5HKk85qIzTtyjpVJR9LsDUsZbEGAoT6gdVD1J1Oc9ikIiWpNAQIXydjdbtuW31LGk4QKPLeMJ9fOcHKYIN8w6A3eLAYSuqQ/i5kroaQHaEFIp2mhQ1gjZ2aDin6YoDeojwctzPAGAz5rJd2YVhefrD1ZVmr13cMTPNN6oOk7bvoORhSlhKAdn2eCXDhjoRfjteUQTZVTp41HarENQ2ueSoE1zdAfxMDjYan2MCxBdociIIFqQXekV5k@bBbpwsAjdw7H7LFpkfOAGRtB8KOlSgBnVc8yKDthuxluDBaIM3fsFNBDmW@AwwiIQ5W0ZTAmAWjps4odlmCoD7WJw2gqQmFHLLktjWE/JIEDYykFkGDgeLypBT7YBu8ePmgJR0vok0DDS8JEluoVSNmigmo4CpRUixtHzYztVK2O8JP19GQuIFwe6UUil99@sbO79/LVtxgz/kT2Nh4MVsqgFjC5tgEGSdQpULLx/eFhIpngV5jQa7lJhB4HFg/g0K3rziSs@PHpYT4ngeUSBOuOElNxdWmuJJABxKmTwR0BdJTUNJFKfVdoYccuL7rmr/BfwlK1meHQ1GwPB7/YTHptHN5xQASlORo5I3eKx@O4MNuU2QXz6sMWwl/0so7bqzt41RT6ujLbQ0OnrotBCVP3pn@tc0eGrf2iCRMGCD6bLgqkQb12OFKUdGoNK5RFpcGhqkVfHCp4reUeoFMubgko8zFwmGYwGdDL35aepjg7krAJYZ4HjFjFI0TNdVRnZ@LOsSsqZ@UoYjIT2sDz4WZ0z1YQ7mA/BPCV2glmPtK62wTqwpToy16rNcligz7pvnKBy2E54ApkeoyV7mBaL40qaq0muWGWeogseeLFgZ/QLqgK44h4xcDM5x4npYprVb1AgqiFUFqT/EXM8s9zdJIFOOmDjPMUeTlR0HxE3w48j/J5y8YSpvQopUIwkB6fSsQBRLtNLsEdyRVwROmxQmmseLT5vlNymcQ7QnmAfU3ViS056ElTAUWNc2YRnxbY/@pZyRLlCvxz8qFsoaB8XPwH9ttPmLUa37zEN18Q1RM1BERQaYYjn1v0mfoZQ5SAWXIWpy8JEMTFlwwbWI8kb6RgpXoiac@TuhWa25cBVyC72lIIV9ZROUkwawrZQJ5I5Z1MZzLXolToC2y8Wl5ptmRhNS3YxPXwxNZo8iRo1YfEpFwDxHYURFqBCLj9ScDw7IFOkrctdRfF2NWTeJ4OsSwrVCC2n2SB7GGeXUmZh9hiW7LFdgHH8SG@IL59kDf45rIwczzCG0@/jDfS6zNH@t@COSp/Dne8kNzxooBrD3PHuDN1aEWiiE5KaufGcMzVgvbgdnfQH6B9qKf9xE7kLA0ALXh0RZlN8SD5HPZtxXIiUvEftqL7EToJbe/uGV/Y@R3Z@Z0Crrn0WHb@p3Y@/Rt3fld2freAe03MyEvRToa//nY9DkTCVPhF7PCiuMvFzC/t6Z7s6V4Bd9OYYf7De5r@nXr6Uvb0ZQEzJvCBA6dwfZibWRIpNkrVauBukVEZiFOYFTCeK03UvfB@aEv0hjfe9SFK6@KL8X8l8X@FqxE91ZGsthaj7OvyrJ5ysDxLlnyRHgZZcU@4vzLUS@@v3LACfURuULxIk2FrKhUVEMgt/hicNmUC@TFYff3NZ12ceW2n3EqcGVZToFkjzJvBFGfJlwqrBKxPmJFnaEkrNeunW/@LyTCyf5JRaIA8Du0d3jMkdxJdBcOx4teyM1p3EHZD6hwhVpHkJGRnMtrbZ5cnq1c1SmwR2RfjlQQ@auN0yZiBytE8gMhkBLTJyPpKq0LXXKVe8BvoOxeK77Ls8Rdx6beSS78tiLpUDFaRypYGP8mLgZ62vbv70B7AtTL4BydgzoLyD8yq/xccLiy7fxR7SJ32W8fzNrRkUYaep5vLCCwjwmWKN1BmWsArY8ZX6H/w3k8@tW1o2ZZBWfEMo/S23EDbhX3V6Tq9/vXgx59GY3fy89Sb3dzezRe/5BOGoZLzp0zOWqi8b6SZYjlfc2KaiCRtTmtZmwMQaJhPstUkbAhJ5vNJs1UobF@aAufniPMx8flAAIBE1LE3xHuSyM3Czx5OQ8keDNHYXo@O/r0ZxpwDyVJDe3TVtcW8IND/Op23BHqDybcdICSQiOwwqQ6snhPTNOleGHnlRFKHXEha@k@9q9P@qMr2OZFISJTgZ5UOBNDY4hf1LTQtMrlcik1gPv4y6IYtJWyT8WvK1HqoFkg@3d65NAtApg/0BRn@2h7O@EQw9Yvpe8I4Mz@SALfOEi9yuIvkzFDggob0AW2AfsdMyRzBKRf3V1tXQ9@1dnwYrQD8ZahwiFbajy2Y@n7oDgCDqeAeu@7wFMdXtWBJaljiVdCZIBMihjW/sYc9fxRUtuIBO1WGeCfcR8ohi9QODUyEEJIYPX@lC4Kpr7FZV1qK/fp42AAYX5G7whIoHV@stFRgiUtoDQ3l9KFNI1qPh9ebcTrxmE4EzNnykaAc0QG/ae83xPe1Ooz@rT0doGGLrW15aCPjZGB@9snhfyYnU2yiIjm5tndhXvmQaYaZS8jF92kVyqnll6D3ypfYAK072AG8TFd1AXezPmU3fBzpNVB@YDqHOJTBInufwHbks7di6vyeFOqSSURayo9x0y7M3cjaU/QxTr2KDLaiA06vPSSXenHJ8krw@RWOM@Ycgz1garM72YY4nw1gEV8EPs0k3JDDmC5lURIiBsa5@aMTuHNtiSv5Q@bXkZhqiwfShvL0X5tBovEVnVPAWuyOsSVe4pk7MYQPEQQ4nAF5M25FxMb8n1mxba7uLpTCfnrLgmWky6FBje@ue6MjkHu0n0F59QR7iL6OLxFicBlmgWUIaqmVrsO4N8hPy5yNR1LtNub@abcp1Uq7jfJDu53kVliY0IQg7d6L4lX3Zpqe2tcj2x7/PdvxvDRexD2ZGUYHyHpwIJKVs3ISQ638T5nJAsYhvZkWMk@/IJED3xiJRDjKtNRoiEapXn3XFPTNoDHpuMOhI8UDKSPVpl28I7Q86MyU2MRSnvo1sjGtkEGXUoqS5zUIF@4hDm67je7/7XbKc4Y9bXQ2gif4703z7aloUsLBZqVB@RAbMUURRgYDIEk9RcQPnpZrpebHdxWg4mh4ZByoP1DoiOodzAazoXN0kOW//M6bLVAUWEwc0ALluyy9hLpZrnyA117Dn@7gVtCnw4Q6@i9MHRC3BrfOPlTWaUsI9lx3FiCYhfoIVELLMoKqgl4ZBLlauSYKwu7ikQ0Igkp5wEnlYWDIoLcQyRfJzMAjvT5lhluWN59IaTTJPzPYYtISybutZMzWHx6Ixpsi0PL1ae24eIoZv95V6pjGctVYXPXbwDQowdK1DMnwVw5Pc8choYK@zKTEGv0YLvU9icbhdx/D71Z0o155XcV8jqsxZ5Ieik@5Qv4@/OkWfapiv9AlFPTtfhmDFaicnBZfP4gFKnVL@x59RQtz7NcVTdXOXtcwBSWmzlzVojvug6bRb2PLMeRVn7HpNl7U4a1Fb9Xyca38AM37Q@5MtFFsDKfHWk2VaudnqxcH6SKcD0PZMHxEz5vvzptGuKa/WMGEoXXKEnNtqdKmlvRJmZur4B8XGxVROaWMp9on8nUZOiMF3RILixcVUEFp7XQ8EF0slagQxZhCNK6ZrlaNXY7sK9Cfb2bOPsaBFj7dT@b7M3ciH3CqYY7fAse6pj7dd52@uX9hfLpPcNuHCWDoxNGne16sLsZJvopmlpKI6pN5CW8fadOIEKNcqVffV8qKHg3tc6gkEK1aUl99enUG0w7GzWkUo/wzlsw@EzNCqaVNmL4Q5RlCkkAwZRgMP6PfVX@KXrVpmuTwdv/Kxc0PduHu4MYr7Oae7/t0kYgsNccgLX1xjCRdj5ETVIfRu@xP7O5v1jnqC8KuP9ghEGtBK70aYuIK@G/4u3fwwpAjeuXOZu4oTWmt1fByrdB3nEyhzz4AmFyra@PHmKrRnnwJuZdIthZvqWlGqZ1PqiXe5Bsg9Rfr9dqHRmQ1XOJLezp1784nvw9ripwaN3iSFKRVTCDdBKxrg664MGgVowvsZv685FpasZhCPJSy1IXB5XRmR12CMDGz23QRYfDrqyYzEa3s3o3/JcmGu8fvSrMwnepY6Y8jVNC7B@gU4pyVhNJo/odz1ym0/S9JNJ0FfyeqrV7zKGX7g2teIMA0K983o0ILkp/updYpjy@@jODL26/etUAgpBZWsIfE10c7Xn17YIXvDYbDVYKvr@LNl@VlKVGuqKmpf/NV8nK90qidvq@IcvV1tSneF0/PKxGxeYpnQ7cOH2TLpqZOHy@EAPrRCZXWcFJTIDoYWkFxcHyORcFueBqONqOeb9C0RM/hcJDBLOlxWUO3qPr5fsbu2IltSTUR6OWFuBRPUdBQLflrEq1X9CVc5w5vBz2UcOWB0K9JM2p6h2LSrSeJhhkOliBvW7xuFe@xXDYID6UNjUcpRN@Asgg4f2kuL0LX69bejqstSRE5KgSJ5tqMmOfDnfNAsVvu3PZy54BgX9U9iSDatTLQaArgPYxZx/X@cMSgzccRA63wj6YaRrWEKGdGdPnlEwpyQVjFJbLhFs2C8GmYDHr7h7OgSKqVMM7UpF1aUWBZe3Q9WWeK6ueowUHq/Ckq8dbSBDYfm8Ild7g8ZPmV/UtO@1eg01v0/6a/i8SexVsPXXIRf3xvrTjVfwiQ@cBwxy6FkU2helauvKuc4ZU04h@Vjx9q9TKahBvRrUFe/B4ZQt8Tm0yonm5z1g2sqgIXo2wUM1fdEwVyzLUYuh2YFTgSZCyjnXgeHDUyeA5@gQd583LopFgdxNMyQeaMZJgaSzCYTcTyOk/HzNwhBLezzA@USfOhycvV8XqKpbqLNevmY@pifvp1295eUX/d9l/E1SfLLBuLpL0KMeI/ixVCtL9e6kOEBphVA/TwJF8aPvP3HUDx7zeCZP36yvFTRqc/ahBf/TWI/v9dTdesvBNXebhm5d2YyrN1W96Lq7xuyy9XMq5v6lzmXktELXafwc7S7vbXivQnrUjK7vnQohQ/aGj3@2vY/sxhI8vr5w8cGSL/Grk/c@TYFvz5Q4fW0L9G7s8cObJHf50Eh4bIyCCSgTSKH6ruUezC7bB7Bdo1CUD440MiJFo0IygE1kwntQaZzHUbQ3XyyxTCL9X1vpTR2GkHrd7SbC2Ux7pkrMLlql6HvTfeF0/F21q5ehLnwbFEIM/5w6b0Nin6PtkCSy5@JO@bOKPZtM2m5bWpKmKBoJOgP@YY3h87ydAvqaWKX5JtWLYf42rN/rJ@PXMN32fpuXs3dTH@3MMbllSI98ieaRzo21GKZbxU@bR2XoeBrTc@Y6J33d9nYN3JSjqyifNLuP@WHfTVGhjlJH9x5Ukd7ZkshZjB561kvIO2ZuqkWJre0LUD1OgtJrnn10um33Ab6a9pI71eG5tf08bmem1kv6aNbDaukRXLUrlyfP5aZEXjTe1DfBn64l3jBVF4u1Nn6jjjVUtYeA2DOr8Pr8dazv80K2Bkh/BHw58dkUqP2u/lcvQTSCf@PRb6IqQNDg8fj85grFIorzU8dAHaHzg@n7NfxI0RU4WPKX5Teq6wxZ/VztJkgA8Z4vkOe9@zVTfJex4mCZRWec@9mXb08xRKTYtjxF@CzLSppcipB3cwvE0p7EDLIT4Y56XyPVDoq1CZRPlukHi@ZcfULRjw2EYCP9yvacT3cl1qJ7QwKfGEuPNiHL@ZxPc9drEMvJ1bSw7Al60kYpS8VAxJhIgFs6EDSqfTWOVTkhk1Wfh0DzIhgYLH@9V4xHgAx@Ia6/W8VHK1L/My3wfNmysJujTOsfAiISc@8GXXaXNF/Jg/EWSO5hB7yHMkujxCv0ii8OCR2zyUyjlcWyQtPZJnJTn5OC2QNS0xhyUI/41b8Nd2GY@dCOsNcLxjuHZNGV0mbKycR7TcD9Xh6kbMXIqFEa4WJ7HhyS8QPJ7aKzZHja@XghGJI6QWwGfsS8eJD3E@VY1j60dO/SPrQ08pFsHExtNzf2onk/cr1gaeY1TfvzwBqWIB0c24OEUdt6NVqBESpO14ki6gZ64uiYW0eKWUuXL6TijrXAB99dySO/EEqXLmjp0vICH/fZSIMRwYnsC@v4m9ZCPRlDI@2iaxIk1iBQUQ@WfclJ2QUP1ang6z6yp0WEcsinqlWBaNZl2cnJ@VRPWs0cQXtRP6cFo9q8Sc6izih0Xf/hTBW4ral0Hqx7VX3jAg3hD/lVZh0uYVweXYS083YnZ/7B/h8kfmGNE@FK0VR1kUL@MJq0ao8DgN4iu2APZloIgPLh8ENOCcGP8GXBBPjYf54lFtQNMIxq7wbjCpF24mzhx0EC9prrtGtQo7vCzhXv0b7ZSagBC7U64WO2IWozhpeYU9T12J8RkDxySk@@BjZAupZqpbMoyV844K5FfY/QI3J7kgRD2cQsMT0d@Kx7DqFkvNSlm8rTTf1MoN/1PEmRfjdKNRusuhb1oIrhkJzk9eOf2bcTTGlELfxt01IXPsbGxYa4ZyNcWHvGY6QxdotIQR3f6eXBmtVyqenhaPTyuSNNGAvbnTkXos5vxtT@zZdbQHrMaqiFu/GOz202Qk@8urZBQ9HUKkWzQYkXch3VrWixRBQpvGY5HnHC8OSPvx2rKpIDGOVi7DdAhS25gGZhY1DOQCke6IdF4PSH@qRR3TdToybTq/tjA90ti5o6lm@0lpjf8JgdxrhlfmZHRlLi64MkexlezUTyHR@0GMZeJoJ7cr48EfiwtnEstUR@EgfzFxh4v@0IVneACKZ7vObXZ8MxwauOV3B71eeBD056NvtvFGTKdz7QrA5v8D)

Another trivial brainfuck substitution, interpreter:

```bash
ruby -pe '$_.tr! "》《十一。，（）!-~", "><+\\-.,[] "' polyglot.poly > nǎocāo.bf
/opt/brainfuck/brainfuck nǎocāo.bf
```

The code interferes with [wenyan-lang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198810). I moved wenyan code and replaced `二百八十一` with `「281」` as described in
wenyan answer. 脑操 code is hidden from wenyan in an「[identifier](https://wy-lang.org/spec#IDENTIFIER)」. First `一` is in wenyan code:

```
吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」
```

Answer (score 2):

## 443. Python 3.12.0, 18900 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPJdSD6UTHl/RHJArsBEKg33iBAstnsaY76JZI9Mx4AjS4UCkANC1XoqgIJNMmOGa1DV2PJXluWbFl@jCyv98pX3ljfjd3rcay8G2FvxH7ZcOwn/wDKdtwbtkP6B7rnZFYVABJg98jrDceNW0BV5fNk5smTJ8/JV3V0f/DTnybwIk9ce9q33YAEph@QrmedmJ5I7kzJtm75eVXjOAy14/XHQ9MJ/AqXIAohtu70x3rfJD3LDkwvS3zTJB3Tdk/BXyVkc@yMfbNbB5tGiGOekn3HsLoAgQTuselYL00P/HKE3DXt8@F5QAx3ONSdrk9GnuUE1DdPyBMdLL2xcUz0jh94uhFYrgNehYUkigu2EiEPXc83AZJrmL7vIqzyQhBFJm/rkN7INidXICsKec8yvS6huRh5JsuLopJ3j@7du@qqkS8KrkPuYQ6veOXIzjhw94Or8PNkp286OlHFsqhe9SwAngLTLskl@apXEarKDCzjajolstPrWY5JHkJZr3qWieH7gm941ijgoCrJPcuDatbD6iSG7kC1YaVuEHM4CqZEYISg23ZcyT7RfTL2x7pNwznjYcf0ooB@oHuB5fTJqRUMSDCw/DgeDe2PdMMUuqZtDa3A7BLbgkhuL4QCoJ0uOTanp64HdR/CdB17ChFNw@pZGCXKBwDEKxUMTAZnqE@BcJwAqIToxIds2GYELc0lIPxdszPuE3ccjMYBgbx1LV/v2AC0MyVds6eP7SBLOuAHVULdTwemE1I1gBMBxJHLcvXhmGbNnBG/3u0SGQga8nFsEguwRrNVIZoG7sT1AGsQKspRCIwSOCujOYEahjrruRWSl2Xw34tdMLe67bthZhazhp4ONFpaZwj3ief2PX0I2OiaFKfv7j8hvuF6YIMbw7KGdRMYQw/I5iZJ7j26myT1uFpEr8PFVVQjZ1AFiciTnOj2GChkviZcqB8vjs1hlSXXkhWSBLSoMsnlSA7ab4moeUCSIpfBAIxA1RS4C0QtkZwC7S1PNAisqdC4C@ADDYLkZHAsJ7OYfs/T@5ZtMuh9hF7E5gPRVHjKOaJBy9AKGgvdd@0eC2rQjBSJViKFIinmSRGeZVJWISeYbA4aTR7uAtwAsQzZBECqBpmWVQZs1i6AjpEWd0lPH1r2NEyBJmGQvEKKABXKowB0tQRQ4K1peGtwlxDa4jUPOxhAbQz0EwAv2NYxsjMz5mhYxRK8pI0NibJO5M0seX@AyQNqAan5EilC8gXASA6yAJhXS5A8eGp5yAKE0PIFKJgGd4EVzh@Yth2CGvgIipagKMMNpSkCfkpQY1ATqoyILsINduCoKrBOFfikCqxPBXalqmDWMFkIh1VYgOov5FgyA90/hoRYOmqXVgp0BwBGwVpANqkg4gAC1CQB9GuYUZLTkHgg81AmyEuxQIAwSgop5UipSADHZZlAnSmQL6QsBTi0AvlREBjQhgLEoUCeFKgBBYAqWp5wcxWgaOgPcTWIC@hSchAnB2aoTKWAN8QDilEgSQXSVNXyjHAhb2oeypvXKEWrBajxIvgB3lTIqwpkhmSslsAf45YAhyUk@GIyyxChIx6gprCJAH0CMqB6FAoXwoJZLYYErdujgd7B/oDF7PQwagGbTgHRCFFlLB68c4hNyArUsootBLKvAlVotIXBOxcnbysApIHgza5FmbqNHYsSY6iYpUT6oT4KZmhTCjRHo2kwiN1U5uYCs7WAYZp93ZjGntAys7HnzLWgoatK@fMMkJxDVx@4sTv27RmQ2JBTaVLmiWXP3ErUrWvq3Z7lD17N8pqjiXRMPXCs41kq@Xx2Dqn6nEcBPRacitp82MASoIvrD9A0K4taxDAjN66ghSwrCs1ex@yNnb4plEtz@aM@wdgLoDOapVlmzp7V70PHPoOjZGkxaec6c87THNqaBn1@5IjYxTQ9C7r828QYgMgSe5YZ/HJ5BkNTEcZU76AkIIAIBz1HGfu6njUhndsG7WlmGdQonoyBNYoCV1YGnqtcmsikVJijDYq5lyU5Ztl4tcQPXctJJUkyzV1w0D8xsXS@d4dO8D3s2bCvRtKFvtilksaMpaacqDdNA9IWBQPoqW0UoDqmoWOvjX2YSfvgCI4ViAQSAdnSdE9Q5qUd6UIyPu1sOx6KuCAZdU3PIxgW5GI/S7tlf9zxzRdjlL1m@epBP2@CONDTLTvOAO1b9IAKDfBO@pDedDHbPc8d0g5oiN2u7bqjFSIOdPKnCOi@e2rOsj6TAfTRyAZJC9xNJuhBZk51KqxTyX4@VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KJBTLMw2K@7DoEFsDWWYxixWi1m9rCOXOnAimQWMB8cTHOM7YtisgG5kG0epS1zyR0IWJaYviGeYhEtxA/ApBdHSQxjHnNBcxpNuqSEXCo6hmfXe4WDTW5@7HRR9YKEzZp/oUaq8H3a050YegMxAUzKHlkiFQDKtBrAlQLrBY@6TrOskghnLqgeALhY5LQoVrxElgDU1QnVyIgjWeo5nGHp/mrDMFUqbYyolUV2I5uYIokbuKKOaQm3NgjQVExO7YQKxh2pZDKQhEKB/1Ag9YJXPjAo80mzrcHsiAo1A9FNGAAQ8xa3Nahs9aeyitGxQiyrWm44Pi4ovEQuUNKL/v9oDYTi0oOzAsiDqDbVAkIApip4loiBxFORLQ8NgmFjFGIwLu0CkBed6TSyC2uh9a5CV42gNQO4yx503JZAQ1YQ0hVGC4vR5Q70tzNAAQZNglxtSA5gmVTKnHHzj6iOu6lM0Yo8XCzmzrJoRxUJ3ZffLzpG8C8kHU7aEyiYQ/K8ZoRAtCEaI7TAx2dMAXFsQYTSlyuMQsRs91RXTvuqZPScb1jmMGgIn5Zp82EGhtvRlLGqJYD7TqUHWkC/wnbGQIHxPklhYGkwpp4W3TgQZkAG1C04dKxJrdIT3Q0@eEW9RQdMMwR0FILS5lapYzpyk8voeaAnUVQmCiP@DWt8nmFdqBoDH9zEm5qDlh1kehAqMjxw0HAwQqfsTKKuMv9vRa8hDi5Erq/HMMs5CD5/yKPIxow0C1ibKKcYAMBXmkZQyQIwbIc6gkDm3OG18vPrjNJ@8NidCL08bcKMB8OFGKnTAfq2EIcNvXAYkjG2HVFxww6ILDa0Dr/nAJZDfOpN2ddxUlXQTW@DqgQ9dxl0AFZMZwMciiD60LSoyHyDt0OyZG2lz8hTpCtj0bn8LuDHrS0cj1oGUw1jOlYxC0yuaoK1TdU3GPkRbJncUOFjqOJHb7AfaFEGFk60AL2MSwpYLOpQO/AFbGVGvgfC5LcS7DtNVTWGH@TmkHwIgJelTHMVFt070pAwLFg04aEpoSy/OAGZ5gV8F6oqhLESmdQs@gd7vIXxEdtN1fTVxEit4dd6zJVf3dQEfxQ5870T3SQ9XdA9EDGlEq2fOT6Sp1pzHnvHjJHQUSjcqePASkgUSo8lTPF7GruAeM5nDqGCl@oYnxWcKPg16JT4MBIzJJjbwDCsPV3KESgUQzPIZ2TW1V0odOXBDgKaAbzQl6SCJ66B5IG9AIQdcsl7sdnZwD9/CIMNllCkmkmChiLk7LdLpxWiEiMC/z5RVZEr5nUIMw17dhCTA4LTntJBYQ@IaYoBF5cJCksIdFByrzMT8q3TDHsUPH@0iKCSRpchaLwNABpGhmLBBBLMMK2qHQcvt2JL6s1WpAbCBTAdvspuf12mgsVARODYFFKpOEiYiBexhg20ilobwY@ILlBoQnoNRanZwFAw9aHLVfcBAI0Mo5SMkRYsN6fmQdj7tXK9pBRwzEY6sD0ckyAr7KgQjAWkPtJqwmF7AKum8SsYrEi/Ep6GvES12xQvkwmGf6KATXwqzM1XAKcxDS6lIUsaih24ygd6eGHYoEzASNnXGjDmT/OBwCixlRNpQJokZ7raUyINgcGBzyZOfofi1si8xT6lhOZcHBdg3dps7rGJyP4j7Yv3Owc/Dz7SUwbKtTueogWblSAbva8UToO2MpJ6qV9XkYM8B32zfDxoiLYXgu9CaCO5kTlaYGdC6TCJ2PD754FSUgCSE6aApgxvuKSMPCgNDFdXR/cKUTJv1MBpKMo0RhibBPIpixAbOO/nqUnyfjly@x8q5mahS6Y87ssc4ARI7SvhPFE9HzigAWeXV6rEekcUEWtRyc35iZ5kNG@XkbZeermaEC9RzJvP343t5BjYINR9cEGkTyA5CldK8rAs3bY1DEl4UB9gcmg2TEWcZRqqZ5XYpgw1hA8KxuyQr4AAA1HtElgj2MiuYPIO@7V8tGXQUjpgBqpxCuypXz8pDxeTM6lw/s4gxUfJf1otRj1lnFTkt7rNh3sdsy8nmzmCvPd1vGLM3uPFA6nQD9QCQ3euB17AvoIs6kyFCsDrN/@OBaxn0qRIIqIEQ5820i0rR8m0PtRbBI0pd2QU9zbVN8j3I8nvBpSUpGMwqi4VMVdC783sQKUnKavZU0hIXUd3b21btR4HAwm45nUKUBNXLsmbweThEaPtCI49pu3yUbEIdJh1GCIDatLOZO33Wu1ZCOjljUBM4yAv/F4Rt9BH2N9ZKqjzTWvNLK5it1xz8FLq0UNEQSxRAFJdHw4of6iQ7ompX7cP@DPehElLwsx2aZXoCCuTgUXWgy5lypAxEgITHMz9ICxtOS11p75CHMzQtioUNGF0fcmXkvdaQcU5SWhl@apXfcaxj/0J1eIS1wYaQFhjmU7T968mD/0d7DnfebgZrPL9hzcrkAiIP0OiALiQOGN2ytG6xpYrEQXALahofNC7jAGBSUaJ5p7HvAuEUMIrIMrKAaNqGbescdOEk/fbUwp@grfOgYjIQeYuNjQcOIoGh3bVRGPDbhjf050s8gCEZ@RZKglQ/GHRGUVulDw7X1vkTjQcdg25KCqsv@Yxzd8JfFgMz4U5PFYENcIDpM6Tiibg9dUF7otDmyBpJi4OnYlW31B6AL49y66aXFmIJpaaQuaAigK0tx2SgDpjbAbfiO6olnpP2WopYYXSuympP4KNhC84ewaz0TVKcU9FaAivQVK2nebt4mU@DSCOkqkAQRN@ggh0@wL7AJCJJ07BT1/Ag5lFvgqCnyCoqjF2Mc0wUuJeXlXFEp5CVQy0BNA5lVwJE3YagHxkAIXAHgCW6PjhvMUWHPN3SnJ26EhiizIPfdgqJqjWfNptMCAb15m@YNZ6wb01ZDaaWr5HqUjTB8ugrUu1A8pN3IAWiXGoE06Zus4Gdd/To76@q0dXWJFAxHYZ8jjMjDHRCkXrrAr7vmfNvDCNK8p7SxEFbCwK@kJQNCNkbl8IGYkqBBQU8LpCdhvgQQelE8BMoBvjUXgcxGM2KBaRoMgH9oJLVLTenrEi46ayHXWMwKDg2LoymwPBoImbagYYYiD5rgiEHArCRBBUKJB/2TLAt0IOHIA5Y@gmpiA1q70BGAOufjUGSAXTDO2YzZ2DA2ydCKA547wgdEF17eJFxEoQHw5Q8@64VwYrFNJHd0pDjAwhXJLowokqfIAqAvn5KAjjR0TVTjcdnEU8dCRUTkqK8AXVdyvS0G3hrhIa3LH/zJ5ce/ffn1jy8//tblx796@ekfXX76b9eEV6hj1jczzaYgZhstwievZf7Wnnpr586tOyWaQ5AnIfP/9y/86t/@2i8t5n1Juj/66Gs/@ugX/@aXPv7rzz760Udf/vEPv/7jH371xz/85I3Sdf7bL7vGf/3YDZM8xaGR@QTD9CC5wQB60fsgtTU2bp2ekbW1NYi@trYFNbG2tUUyZAueAjzXoN/cAt8sPLdIA3zXSItctDjQYH2yZLRPpOPnoqkbgzZwS8NMaWkRuryz88k5GQwaExHa@TFvbPCtCzq7RPsCnHFhmd7FSjukK2cw7@9A981ss8yvSrohNRtys9U8SzW7mXTzQsoqLdCy2xY@/JSabiiiKIAb8paUJJ6VLqQ4bxMaEgKJxsCb5YxO2LGFPKhLM4K/Z02gJwJWCYQ0PyZPWQud3MGh1Q/M0WDqzQeIx6tAPsWx59n6EFxGg/xvnr@8ZPHnRaEFHTmSGFk4EAtx2AsljdGU8UWO5bQpLSxPinqsE6E3dANdelcEdUOc62iSa0lJEKAPoT4MEi32Q8s3QLXQHdMd@/NjdEuHDjF1cD0ajIF97w6sEWcaAxcofRtgkniWBJGMEz4CmzaKonUNEW5s1sgycIoBemO6dMeCyqetl45iKDTpE922uvFYdr4weiHGqVVpHCJjQlbfcT1TAERADI6uU6LL4Lh6NJu7T0eKrvHK0Jd2Ach3LTPIknu2q1OMug7Qwhw14lzILD7osxDlwOxytkOEHogWIqsBz@xKGxyd23S9AbBLKA1O2ahxHQ1DD8n1R10xmEBULoUd1Lwn04ZASDslXVVVC0a@V4n8kBYA2QOoGtTiHFAJIy9BAc90WLV7bBgl0mkfPb67x8YaaOeE3RGOO7WHbncMclioZxyYTj9L9oCKLMcdAit1ovgvj@0D1w2YVgyWVSMZTMm0hmNbp2MkV4cxboxnuB3XpkMnN0WdhR97vm7rbNAm8t159yHIxk@PDmtiZS6QpJ8Mb0wbx@2WJ8vwuT8/U0dnKaPpFJ8RJr@e57GbixZaInMJPUroMcSllCArhlo0tcaOYcAzRb7AsCvVjTicQsMxGWmW0JmiUveToNdbcNao87GAvMSeOeeoM1teuaAOeZ1ZoDwLhGstF8LMAyrQMPGSy5XhijQcW84BxDrzKFEPnS7AFHDofsG3TH1nKzBR@gk5WDxhPzDtaALuwBy6OMkEvaSNsxkg2qMgy9ZImtBXjHAugbJpnKGCLkGHiFcFLWhiI4GF5hJrtNl0LEfCiSJuXSLhCHGVNhzQutnMns9YqAuaMR182KyzGWHUPDym9Ehs7Hq9DSA269VowdqqYJhSMhkHo1Bp3iAGLSadBL9W1HhJg0@HpDkapcr5EgjdE1UWmpPiXus8KfkUDT3CN5uTW7L6PsgkuBpx/bbUN6t0PdAKfFUjnyRl2GFfztFQbHjXGAB3IZnJIiqhfsZOz7W7AptLAlojTAvBCgon9ONVkuFiWNPyogWSdIUqi4pcdW5t5TW4V6q0fj3A3GrMGBCKD@T8OHtyThrHWXIi@iPbCkBEQnliEK4qcq6u26TzWbrn6VOfC9eD1MjOwdvvNuQWg8ANdZwfKrFanETLf0Fr89wxLtgGE65qCayA9vp01t7C8oKQAxHoVAJkH2CwBKokTigsEZV8zPNZWXom6HMpk4pL02GWmOkLsWfrQWA6jObYJN1qdLPZlDCZGk1@KxyarxCZzl9YPcgl@EEWq@Tw6O7ewYGIAl0quYfzHBVojiA6gjCyqtARJucLXyG3uklyC@OkUbnloKmBut4O4wNRV4HoxybO5iDb6ZteChzTOEVhgDOdFaIRmTQWIgjXJhkBxVEMLAXK9hYDVlma/6fOseOexjVeAYrPUEwCulO3KyhlpsWxY70QfeheqKAJQUJ9CnqJ2nqKcrJ1JR0uPhviBCsI1VRAhBI0GgR0Jn4dAvOk1aqymXIIC37ghtjleVoVdJV4TYmqvgbOIMhQCGH02ivyrCEL5VZmfRkouhArXODNyj8HFyEsgvbNpcmup2h7v9aQWR7YjBnj3k99uvxxcZtDhawzA89GZmnwaHERZTp0LdLimqLFFUvQyJCV0AELLEjEEhLh8vuQZqk/5fyg9WI06pBKk7MY6SqinJyfUxySdZVQHIJJIawyLiKtGBjTAxdK8yBcej8vE9DWGi63wDbb5PhKrM2Lsijz6MTkdOnkijAqnFDfSDNnwqDlHLt0OiQ2tWVRyaMAGMceHtvXY@JKTfpYCEonUxeypYrF@Wz5w06PPpbEodMB4UQzdaADzaHMC8KiLh3QFx1zvh79yuKKyJnp92zxJu1bwUyEF68JKZRLNHCv07FWBYXS46qp6L0UCwdIwaqYE5VZEa@uvyELiA1Xk4bv//5RFxB8Hf0D6AJw5C02tKFTxqoQlmF2ISpa6GN5zbEB4rFt6RQB1PQ6kIbuQZF0OzYsB00noQUBOvYhDqmHNQvEhw8QJVcmo4Y5ZzNi0Xt5IssmlRxghsaqsFfWI7Gk6PQHKGpdigQm3lgmjUSZEqsEc8KmIOYUZWRQr89UtGiIUKJl9T4YB2P2BGn2tZVojfBejoKFkHJe7yimxNZv31Dlnn487rrC6LgfS6CFJWFnpafjQwJ09OF0aBuNy4vPCsjWQ0fvVcFmnZZ0Sl@vowrfGfsjoUO16i6z0YYwvCEFz2bPVUGscP9bbFiNNcumjzekxBA6EEq4GkDCFZfCHNKsK2i29c4UpYvB56eyeGYdOE7NyGRkbcXU6mi0Oj5qkjR@ubw89kQ0GD6W6fwSW9UZqlS0wOE6z9fUKvRH1lC3BbU7Z1zJtJdNzF8LGs/p0Ti4BYHuQ7iRyLHjMca27s1MN5D4tWHkawPSUedoGS508COiFEVFnTHHaBHYDCQun6WPuYl@axnCou0TQmxa3thdI8DFkSuo5w1YF1uUiEs/58hBdFfhxHBP8V7l7Q9AvWTP5X3Xy6W5egM2JNiGrUPPvJLxLwzr4bDha0jy1PJN@liO2OOlGQ0Me6n7IrFHA3bzA3CvI2Dfsl2fHNLnTQjqe4AF9lxOuvO4tHRHoIPX8@YbuE00mz@rUN3uu3ah1Jd0eKys9bHXQw4fvt@Ul8W8SFFew4siQcd1lPC9koMfS97x6yqIbtrzcCXnnPGGznQZQwpnK1aXDoR73KmwvGT35BKNKUpsUG9Fwrh@5VSfRu@foZNYhdqokxhNqYAMchxGKJfAEHhMaP5ZUsvdnFr3zZjSNbDF1xVirnKPbRO6Jfq8VqVElZXPGUOR5TdnUT17bI7NparD486HZthhvHnicpjd9XAsHYfvcctFHOplqMy9Ue6w50XbjUxDx@m61wsni8xrBPL0CNXcJ2B4gobrMfrOeLRQewt6lXPAUDMYRU3U7S7kAn0@L18pvUbGWZCsfZPeN@o6TDfDpU21vCzLoegxN/exYLlJB9LiuB9a7LmQMHWZpTwLi/Nd3pxxeRoULfOL51ayFHWV6k0Dl8uSYzlmMMXnG3LHjuvan6emgEnihlcX9EyBLhK9qcauiS/h9gcyG1zwcUii01s1rMB6j1ArBPyguntTpc9PzrxRbQo4/TjEqaFF66qRlaeOrQ87XZ2kOqdu@jpQ3IuJozNslah90yANHZ5QxJJYnNVO1@2Yts5ek0LupnhlUVvStsNZT5wlZXOjs5nsxBXeMZpCWa0uqAcDc2hS6w3itd7FUx3C18pAExfvVd4T0zSkyZ5prAowsqBZO/hcmIydk10C1wHFJsAFZqgg2LiEMXRdjayHume5D3YevT0/qx4G2B/qffNepB3MDQngChmmOM2MywcHKuQONiUDooVgQ8HSOTanfvReGvHh1ICKGg9XNjoDhwXfoJWtWvR4vQtzBu7AGZgDttI4tq2iUiCkgAIOqcfpD3CR02i0sPh5Hg@2a9vzeEAWwxiO6/aWprGHmyBx787S@Gxndfh67TCVHrDGh4aVZDowx8DHfTdwR6ZAbauC2jikwZ6reE40R/uzjpXcqNECKqL3zwr/tbpVX3eD0Yi@2iN77NMHjSrQPaqvkyd6bFEFXf7men3xpTvsiKGjGK64oNO4y9t0xwqMAW4SZhRp9t2OMbBel@nwYAIpGtxg1jfS3RAzFhHuojMo9IBebyoivdTm/Q/xtb@q0sNxEtYZxIYb@vdlY1F0G64w0o8Nn437oYlUcOhzrnWxzboVut258mJsBTOgc6tw4oFMNtCOhlV5DxcPrJRE6Gr4GTsMFxWspFIqvKKgKpgyCAjKqmQX12XNNTFNY4@lvMFwjeNexJ5XYjJckEKHuKy5wUdwXyCdhZU0SyVrZzDu@9d5Gxtz7oK0go/VGjldkDo37grdgu6Er1UYVG0Jd6rBuw3ix9i8cWIgf@PMAA2n2ILuWvBqwwtqZbxyeMi2Rj57EqGnrgoWLrABNfPqrBbDzXS5nhhWTNfssXF8NL1OJgP9GoTXPvTngoETvTgMjHyaddqMJzluH/i1YJNZ4CjsKl1p6QKY5dUfd2/C@4/Mvo6rYR9YAa4bXEIVtH0sWzjzWthfGuu@9aUxlGwVseHmezZn5s0vm0TbEngP9b5l3F@oiDiTIYLDRYfstUD@6HS9Lk4Hlo8LbmLDDWMuSHKMiJHq2iBCLwl5dfA5Pndg1oDYXraloZcNELujKW75mVLTTWPDVkAHEMP3Ki1q1fKmGzNxOh6Oxn74Wp4HuqRnfoB1yNiZf2oBcOEFcE0y0O1g@SDs3GgiCFJhfzczLk@yQj6wbLdPPijJBOSugFgo5y4hnDvQ8z7B9SKes4QSadpvOHeHOr/A5Db/BdStiSvTHSu4eQAjCHDtSPTGwrBOwT0FeeABPsXtzwtBOFqOkQdznVy8j/Q1XTRQ2KE79gwTjfHhEPMSeQjd3I2Wvlq4nR4Ptzid12wM14ZmBAZ7adMwXGccCN7YuZH7F27k/hU8IGiuuknqS3sPn6bna50uEH6dIBkdITUzrZzdvkJMlgOy1Gp@uRg6EvvvsqNtDug61dfE2cHzdwzKlu@6y1SQJ1PoKJYx8/HwrmngXNZr03jkPnQdF3qXETC@4YHJNmIvrDJYHhGjPcCtxoCH7muTOaRgV3QqTHrQR2YH6tGemd6kb2GA7@qBvqJrocNeVCWLTa@lCcvumN6HdDxrzrxKa1zM0H1zQtWA1YTB2poQGAaTXnGoaaEtLEwu@CPXddiTck8ZXsrDm7kEsHb6ePPZWxFXey@o3ktVqcWiPj5hSxfMLjspYFVZPbPj2ux5w4IYx2IT1bpnmb70ADeeU7dCjgggTfk38orijbxipsWAZHqi@3TmeLlWMAOpTD7HupSB7hkuTtqEhhuWjMztFn8NO44XkLPZ7A4gfgKcSTfG4dmOr8uWPewM6WOlAjBXmwcmJNPFlWqHUyfQJ9crkw2@hPvL55YZxbuyI7aEjbpAUk9Au0gvV@CuYM8a0QflvCtncOlKEcGxTOOljgNNLsXLbHh1wR/KJj2ixhXDrXPNhQ6ESjrdZry0xSyumwJBxDaFYOCBGi4FN43QRmdcLBnSHw9NnPdcnEhYKXK6/oAW1l0@xRszUc8UwuPWgGfER68xuU7YWSkxInj4P77zjgSdaruQi859ABb1@kllyPzYc8LXm1DaE9cPetbkMeQbF5evYhtYrDxEgRdrAWjaWFUIqD1nbLMBgf7cop9hl6pRAj08VxBsypYDUzCdE4GewjW5XiKX7RuSdvBQ1cDsCuEmdBwsFx5EW4jiYOF7yZzePA/EFYWKxBA7KeTCNYbLkHsacQCQn9xAGPn0LY38J/sPHh@JI19Z2g/tDHDR/TW5bGFXu1qS50aJPtS9uak5thaqa/mBdOdQEXYf7IsYYAW@2ei9AC@cXFp4rRyKjA7SlPSV2gv6msFyge/@0cMHmdmOO5LaHXju0EzPe@8eHmZxA8M7h0u952Pfg9bRcycro@/vKUp6CfmG2zJXccklKa2CdGSCFgnEeJ8divFaIcpwR2b3aDoy34VOEjm1/4bJF1YW8pF@YvWxFZLySkTRhkrKYiGXnlv3C0qy6cXvVfV5bI2QWxr0JbHXyhUSKCFokqctlxJumpy@Kq0QOZwc/3yRFPk6tc4f5Srp/j82Y4qirMLzod6DeiX5lZW1GGDZFKftnrzBbKgZKiNC7CQEQFWC9drFykVhCKxbwgeOmIeOYOysXJlxE4DYubC0wZ@azlR3BJSWQpeRG0sZH5hzczXxYpETPOd56bRVvN6apAxqjNB85M157e7e2Y88Dph7aHv70VPyRPdB41kC0ZyDOJMsPhRwvAaP71o1cLHf9YBTs36iP1pO9xVyqHtd15lO5poKzuJiV0dPrIzjoI0GMm1rYi3j3QYbn3myfCVIlAZbIe9OF@S8@RMxwgiXX/lVRZFlet4JvhWZWa8QMEmhSZ/iYVnzXkf7Mekb2C@L4JBeqlU9MCe4YoCNUi5TTpfy78INvL2YXs0ub/Ir3eCXuyG9a37oiJsplBsA5m/wI3kx9n7g2qcDV9zVPfMGdNyU9fINWS/P8ZvwCGY6exWaVwutuBI8fC2ltyMz8HKjgduxcgsi8uLOyZXD7YHu0fUHfTdcPM/sy5M6HUcN@aH@0pxvwsczPmAOxrhkfMlEWgcEMdPpW@zENXLHDfao7QZtId4Yunyu2RrdHY@usBI8nP4Kd3oPlDL31Cd3cKvPTD5colzi2qLl7quEKRKPMOHhgvePdqJEHx9K6lyKs1y8/2TBGTfDBY8P59w8czJZpW0Jk1XKy1KfWaqPjnILyW7Wn528Zl8F9GzA6uL3yi6X8Z13Dq@3TtQUBsHQjnze0R0zgtN1A7o7Kh6Hm4xmg6PvDSgBRHxsyYIu6EUsC2D4UruNp5W026uo5Mh8nw4sQ19JAnOCYj0T8MNDgcxJbhCE3@ugUVY2APc45tqHo4HlTELLcOaOa91I6kM/KvEOObTdUxIpPHPNJ@yxIIp@Yjo3b2oSytrNHbI23@su4Imd@h@@VqHozore@47pecvCHBjSvcjyrppeEuKdwyjAMt9d28VB0q41Hi7zplEzmWVe3kLDvhrJWuaBh9YfD1zPWeYZVUylcsdcCXrtBr/hFLS1ZR6dXm@Z857vLnN@OLYDC4W0yPORO4bWE5HVnhdJb/XNerMpVsSZFc/g9Qdeet4FOMXQHfsg3ll2@mpQ4UMrWHC8gm/qhocAm47ouFfhvuOSL1qzfM4X4uVKLL1zb@azOE48xplCujtuZly1U2o01V5Lvi@tPrUsJzzHGl7xnZ2vtO@5DrOl5@d9otOVlkC7r9tWevVEqPqamVBkc8yfnGjLWhkw/HvzGH13Ookl5yc23asb2nZVKEDfMNLhNyJ8uvpS0eYGBdiSkRXL3mYs@0t7Q92YH3JcOGQhmjbyZ0x8TrPwDh/d2Tl678mD0P5FfdiJUojORVfvslVb8RqNK8Mo9OR46RCfgj/Qoe@iIygCbpu@MoP23s6DJxE7HoBIDqjEw93mBppivktSXc/Xh@VYgnwY7VO6C20PzTNOdH9qusI4LhTr75ap@St3D1w9HOrm0HNHOl2rjUdmcDj2eumVG1nV5crO4YNVbPWdqJiHbz9850v3ZtucHllDIosq/K@0DFER5atO6nUn7bpT7rpT/rpTQZSvyHwrpEGxdNPmZU0sX4etXMu7ej2j6vWMqtczqsYZnXOSrzstSXEJthR5iVsYjm0uB0li/vh@PxseI8UOY2Bb4H0x@sZCKuUAA08vfupqfj8/HnKdWsdDXtfp3n0Ie35O1sL98uDBRzvwwxMC8CxIyxmbuMWffewmqK1DMrWaki@TLfyOVIUoMk0TP75XZkfuRYk1yPpZuPu9UlEuyFqN8BWehOcPxCdos1OgATCeXwuFIsKxQtYD8FmP9s4T@lkTck7o2Kxg4DGhYBOl@VNEquHpApCn9bMn@0/2Do92jp4eNuTWRXj6QFQKx4HUojNObmldHgof4g10YnYmPD31wobk6LcscEzXj8pF8DNOi0WrLRRtVih@C@OsnzmOJNEDGCThAvIn8Cw16otCKTgx2FGJaQWFZ29U2FkI9EgHqCMGmqdpQqVViLws4ZHu@1Cs0P/ql9CoL35Jr4Lf0sOEw2O8QQbuu243TNE3yeuvKMV7O/sPnh7skSiDM6o5tbrBoFbOs1PewwPeeDyOwaYnlSTDKEmoq1oteS8JiEmKSVKhR2bQE9bxMLhkTA942EYYe4Ok1il8wGAyrhTpv38kXSRF3MiRhrDJKFNJSBZonhIKHod3BERC7h7sv7t3QDD/e3epM6IIQZAj3NX/F9/vsm@URKdoRV8R9Iahzge15btWt4KHaBgmSeQUNTyJp0vwBDl2zgQxJ/R7H5Ty6IDT3HcF0/RkI27@5I/oOIzZiR1Yc5QDzMdk3xKhJ2HEHzGJv8XEcfSkPqD3U3rQ5JUzGNP0nDP2zUR2OmoMmpJe9D0EnJAFHZXKKZZv4TkcWA89d@xdaSS4RZ4eOSqSHfzAIn7GUaef24HMjp2AHdkWHuOUAAoVY16VJes0s@zjPPxcwOTmGjSSjtm3HOI7FoilQYV8CBSMk6EVdk6LINST16JEoCvUJKAiOheQKc1DPPSeCKM9PHuv6UmXv/JLUr9KwByA@ZPQPJHvgO1roa0H5q8z8zMJCVRKXvsmS5yX@QzhmaxhCVhGuJ7105/iN1f51LqiHLe9k0wyL1fhoVTzJE9urTcFYb0h17bXdUBk8GLShOYsbeROzLuDXne/LzV5HmTXnCRtnJ2dJe9tPLGe5UlB6Fpq4cVkeqEVtBeTC00pvTgeKYWG@GLS4ku17HGr2WiRJ0/ef9V@leYnJ3TIMgUEtvuYV3J8olImZ1sFLXFcxu@xQQmPyUu4jnsE/9T8sjtn1tHc6QHdJnmSaDbxA6l8kQe2l2zBn3KK53AxntGoi3Vxq/XqVbqh68FkSizLGvndLtzugKRUNX1IoKndhkbEIkikSd8UiXDlh5MemeyY/f54T59a43vBtlgUS6I6x5g2H37wXnhV33v6lJCn5OnTlwcr2Fgrk0kJQoOaJ5HjAxAnsxNSaev5BH5R7S8@W7vInj1pb/7Fx0PJXMPXY3x9cvEQzYdK/tba2q07d3K5rKqqzPzkgyc/v7Ozk7ubzT9p5Ldygry2@ed/tramqpuqtNbyfaWVbBwfv8@rco4X/@J7yfaTJ1/y/br2Xz96VVfwUYTHCSmSMl4aUcCIzxLcCsnnyZteiZcJBa7ElP7aicj9bI0o9a3i//jm4xeJIFFXpfc8eAeJF4lCKcGMYACbFtlOEvXEJgYrXCSmUq1WA2Pxf/w7iF9/B@Cgz3QTHvV8BKswTdSFGo1ynqgXwKCoKqT7/3z00VwOgZ8BK6lBixRKkds2MMRGg88VVX6rBdcGvTY5PL5IkCUpCucEg8B0iVK6rdxGiwUWeDnwwjGnZgK/Kfl4m4jPDjLQJ2TEd@tr0t1NAS5xJCmK2lSU28B@hVsbtZoA/QpttpqWv41HS6Zpb9h3A5eYt99buBLv/U@5loKpvvdPcx2QXcswPTfLJQpr28/v1utQcq2ubdQz9AqbG215xRLvutvAdY4GY89y8TOV1Qf4wZU6L5dUPpvNbh@0IQqZTBCZwmQithEEYR/BTrBLbBPmgg07dGRUCVcdeUKLxO4sVmSdhSPPkw1oLa3nq8Ml9vD6y//wl9/@y2/S37fp/Z/wFCina/WkDQh0Ag2nDtd2pWLU63zd48@aaK8DtcmVUqUktS@aqY1GvXUAAu7b58m8liSH9jTbVvFqppsNGr9Ok62HyaO9npg515lLfd4t9GCBqQO8Q0yRRFTOuXLFWCPkSjguES1gEhon9ZaAY6A1oaEU8i2BxWpsQ@XwarHMt1sJYX2KeW/V1bz6mGzX2UUG6z5xMTeaWogKEua3PivbzGdmq887JepRtPoszOcNF@apDCXzpVD2rEcZ3V6rrJUqhYoqteurr@osBl40qGmaT/zESSK@qiSkwwifiZgy59yezddEXC0kImCyEPc14bhEo9ZomS1oI@F/2UWrSysofDU0qW2eVIE@VE1Q@21eVqC1bbcjdr4F1xr86B@u2IrPNeoSOtMg1681UlE2VE3K3yrsqdgHX72IJzTqGcojhVY9IyKvFMQrgTjoVYjR6XReGh2QUXS9oxu6EuhjfaJP9aAz7kw6gTE28OvD5AkKeu0QB57m5t2SG6FEFBJaXllP3EYK19QyfsgXtJRSSSurWlHRigWtKKulvFYqa8WcViwCQK2oauVyTlW1QlErlLRCQSuU8WPJEKYAYTSEUMxrZY1LvGqskQPG3yYkE13NzGuvpyLlaHhRg4u3ILiTBIhQY@M4yyX@Ca66oipkA7pJGR4gG1IjUekPSrirW2M/y5EEiH1nrVcbjVcbZL62hDDP8BLb262McHHRAHO1Gv4367GxSi9mgqK2LjKZzWd1kIae1RsZAPksBCkKhAIV23XS2qRecWphcqH/ZqvVB9/MyO8jyQg0Ey8gE5nNxmbN3aW3SFun0IJUNhdyvr1NSW0bYtXXoVtIZzLrgrDWANCNsIOCwEiQYREBEgRLgShzdvYz3mRzE5jMxeZF/aKxeXGxuQn/Tfq8CN/geoE@F8mcmyy428wS/ulrdl1cLPhGYWb@LeRTzYZUb0rNkFe1wC5KdXQRpSYY6vCGcA1NLbWwd0Q5SGz98/yL2dkzdsEst0TINZfYIBsJPD9JS2xwieeXn/4feDcvP/0ByrQEfmaFS5wRwiWkjTKhbvRVBsHuoUMesssBM96RFV3Qof4QHR32cFBTlqTnIqkIVF1OKaVCWsTuv@322rhBVSTPISgE2@ub0Igi3kt4tVTg2xllqpLEJl8oUnb7c9euZDL5L56r5WKSaeO4w/K57/sP53I5yycErqqyIijndXYQLjup/OeWXf/i51ZdXOK8TBBHKcLwwiWAjBKSBFokl6hvDnG5H37lQ8DPtZ3U3hee7gi77nCkB1Rdx7E8EBVq@3u1crmOapS5/oQ2no27G/BU4L@3BoUgzR4EbfZqxhBE9GZPy6tN1Frf1kF7B0YndF7g78FL/JEjA38HL/BHjl7i7yDAH3nYwd/RC/ztdPB3NMTfnRf4e/gSf0/7@Gt@QdOUKr@un3QnXfhPXq5P1s8orjJKWblYn/AMZ4mtevMLgE4/WSXbyS806KhQvtxqoG8LPL4QeNOKXitXRzW1OqwJOTVXfVlTBbUaftTC9bP@1M/iKk3TwJowjRSvbql8usooRcuV019g4zSVds2mgy4khd8ISbl@OgOGFHRi6Sj4KyEEJVp@9H3BFNvYW1HTOESilfOuJ@jE8uEBDhmtrLhe8iff@PjjZK2WFJL0LPgcuAn4gWl4gEOjnFXUbDGbyyqlrJKFcshZpZhV5GwJ9EpJzarZfLaQHWZfZrWsAv9Wo9F@1lDB9hJ@Kty57MtWA/hr/nax1Wq8bN1Syq1MToXMQJZy6S8AGohoso9NVUeALy5RI@vKuiLbsiErHaUDBovIHpEH8kDpKlTZlE0iT@UpkYeu0gWTCT8ZTJbcI3KfyI7sQDDwBVPQlgM09eDVh18PAHnws3CVU0eRDQIJ2aiQ0s88KW2MKZ@3ydsD1w@yoybXIEnCPzefP3@OQ@piwWrhof8N/vnzprTRUsslImLTE9uN581ki2/yeCSsWs6RztRcaz7nQYCSedZE0YUkfL@RbFUTUrMpsQoEzFPSurhot/ce3W23JezJm8SsZ7Yz0A1tb9egWwpfW4l6datZoR1d1NklpM2tZl0T0FzIQJ@lghu5bwLlZKXM57xmgOFdX6MIaD0/fQ76WuoUtbbTE3idRob3mvBoM32Oekun7zXnrNQAF4aVpPeWQFgwQK4dbxrLZvAH9fef6m/98/o/fErSqUYrnTq72EzRK42/dPrs4uwifNbTqVRoSW3CDx3AjlHOLupopIHOwNRIpVvpiwvmBs9UepMBrKdJarNO487CQa@XiJOkybJH6n/Om8SFSYVXM1l9zm9uesZ5s0p5aE4ukwT/HHQnfTYz0mxOZOANneioasEh6/o5HUZOVw38Dtx6p6G0/vx79DjyrTQNlM9Vq8oGYRY1p1aruchWLFWrpciynkqVr191eUspgIaXywGHrYJlKwIrgxXiNsirDKmRJjxbt2@zRErq@XkEU8sVMjLOSFWrUUp5SNb0dYO2c1D8zvYf06O8gVHkEwT5QTimnpLppwBOdDuV5Cv87dup8GOvWzvp27fVsnx@HruMRuCkLDi129A5tNvorp2f822eTmaU82CXS@fnilzOKEmSdr3UI/xiJ6SVEhRyS63TZMvAl9VcEbyTzYlSULBv0GnfUCjhSfrmyEvxTYdPr9X4ZLPpJHn0y2ll@rljD5g4tWM/Ak9EAOsUq@R/2ZXkk1U@cUZxq5SKjK/yVXSem3kCTkPOLhKUyEgun04BZ06DBH6RwJ@HTJx1xPl8upqT5cTZBc8CK@UyC50muUKqlCmHv9pamtRBvGQ/lJG1TG6juLGNg4U@vSbXL@Tz1TOzplzUzswKfqPmomqE32rEXdDm7dtaGaqtJCfI3TGexZBtcmEnUQNRAyVVeDS5ZDJDbt3mcIu4l6xUtynRKaU8SSSrzFFIQmdDSlD/krqRV0qIGc7q4dkGIG5xCsXMGlnjVPrGB1dm@FpDxwSXiFny6/5cFy7SJR3Sx4v0UasnFrHpRWzC/OnTMOJALrtC39hK49JxgMjFjC82q6HlNdawkuTB2LBwPPHJg53dvaOsuimQhHpvZzerHj69k1DQmp/ZqbeG9oO9nbuPn0KEJw/2dg733t5/d@/pE3D3yensivu0qGeLe7g50xL7KXmP@9B7qZumbo5Ns306Hp@@IB9aVtuCKrfHUDa37xHfbEORRvqseFW4DcvXP/xQ90b0Ipff/crld3/h8ve@cfl7X7n8vW//5NNvfwXu78P9Dfb@xh@V8/j8yae/@geXv/t74Pif4P5TuD/7yae/@RG7qf2HcP@XObcfhvdcOHZzAOtrP/n0m9/7yadf/w7cvxPe37l@/8pny@9vf3n1jfG@@Qc3h/nGv4P7DxmsKOw3fpe54fta@N9l4b7@nctf//fs/@fhD42/d/nrP8RHaPnl7/z5f7n8@D@qaunP/83ll795@eWPL7/8yeWX/6V6@Zv/RpHnH39w@e0//us/@cO//pN/Rf/fp88/fJP/5Xd@@a/@z7/6v/7qT8L7M7j/PZg@@6v/CM347/74u/j/5h//3Z9@F///@@//3R9/6@@@9q@p4beY4R9@54/Y80cff@VHX/61H3386YrnV258fvoG7p/@E7i8eT7fBM6blOvzunz6M@XnH4ONWSpAA0C5v3j5m18F4v116KMuv/J93JIB94r/91WFhvk@s/1/wKBeLzP6yGCC@1uXX/kGeR@x9L8BluBP3n8feqf3w179/fffDzH4CfqB@/vUkV2LEZln5Dvz@YTMwkE1/DYhjefPWzhjvACaWn7y6a99j9oSZqVOZwOx1y@ppcwGqG0b5XI8TbiJ4b8ag/zC7JdYhJQvaY7jVMMcfIJcbCGxT5D/XX73o8vv/cvL7/7W5Xe/hv2/kCtnd7KC8ppZVwiYf4NwGLDwJuEwICTfztDhUiEDZvNcwj1D2@eEVKEcWklrzoKbUq@3UYEfgUelsnGWFbaaIFfSEl/QuLjpCERURVBvZbbWJKLoWW1D0yGglGPhSMXZlnOZ4oauS1z7XMINSuSczBklhYWU1BCXzAsXakkhZElRY6/1CEBcDC6RwexmqES0EclpeY1MMmFJJuHMPLpDoMkGNU4Im0@ZUO8JN6ET@NF/ZpxwJEOFJHrhR6giIzWE8aLJ/yLcYUHykFZmNmVDpUfCBLcN5kLXNdDEc6BJ0anQzKRWRwNONYDXHdBbarUMRqyxTIGV5a9eIjQ/mUwNCo@xWZxsu4QgJncoFIhZo3ioTVjEDMKrRzjJcOhEc5Mp1e5CgrXJXXTIIHAK9vnzWr1Um9QR3CuGlMwkc4fmCYHVMpP6K7DXKEyIxyXuvoKslGqZTL2ECWIhWR1l26ym8rRwtOw4qc4qAt64sm1rm5BbvFLi2YTVGiKMhcZnZhYaA2KUg@e8ovLP@Zwq8xC4mdkIy0b/kZHeGxT7azTdMElWdkx5jQIj7ecbz8OANCSkJgiiKBK4cRXJFtkmWxzDWiZDMwOvTIhESiyUOGIHQjHFZWitM7QBfHCmn@okqpqrgn5SJejkGRx@2YsuTZK59QkuOzsjocwsh5@rvOB0CJOTNe7sXA@Xpa3r5AKcChyGoGnWNj73hZlFrK2vr3OJOq/xj@n0e0aSiHdcoYsLoe1RTatC@EKZR2eTrrRkWHyIOxGyHDVXsZjk8qPvJXJyMcGtJ@mngQlLiNzKsHt7e4PcArTS95zbhK7hEzKam3MTDI2bmQyvQqJ1F2wbFIUZCo17RhI1/IN7gpIb9MZPdM/ys1yWMr4svMRaAr3J48ePw/xSh2c1LgPtUNUUtOPU63g8huhmF5c5ZLOimBWz2fAt0jd1EEODSH3Dt7iOqCfzGqFSLOE3QR1jgHjhXr16BbTBIS4q@04QGklNzZWoJ6FkMMHVdfowy7ETE2x7Gi3iVXNljg21EKWQIyRFKQKuNMHVqimg8TTHlrwx8oquVFItlZI0JNSYmIJgDExBQU7FlgXTvVEkX1ywQs7mrTh2ymYRcP1FvB6X5S9Vyqcjz93HZPfxw4d7j45GrVoLehv6EVqzPfJcw/T9FHruPLrL6FctF9I42Y2lP6qoyDu5vYqMhJzZv3uwf1ghDGdh5aVoSap08UKImbLCJUaj9zYTHs5leCaPn2By@UN8VmbISKllDaIm6lzCMFFBA0rFP9xVcmD2kYAf@v077oSk5CzPZ5UCqtVpXF0A2fl5d0zwiEV2rgPwB1w8KUKJMef1M2FuNg8d6uRA5ZhBUKiBaOVSZCgyg1IsYIDH7OtkGlc/3DsCyEePiaLKIjlwOxZkqv4@mYiEABc4cIemmxUuaGzkSUfW0MUQNs499IPBOn7xlW/K/ByC1htyFn@qpsFTyRWySr7YWluzzwSE06REc4ZLQy/AeiYgTt6Ci3BvceQtcIJLuCCcOzIdEk6M7D@uMvLFHcMkBbk/DDxeyQNnSHM4/xPC40bzVxWxDk1tcSaVS6x98EFA6vW9R3eF/Xs4ejEZkGhhqWB1xYFISac79kzq2yeka71r4W4GsWv5I1ufQjsGhG3UASMBTnMnLi4uegBz/x5R6yq1srhdfF4Y1KUD5ouJzhHg0T0ucTsasOGKtyuV2islV4S8VSqvNFXlwIHbkLiE1VsDcqNLgzYk9uOdWk6RM0o4yeOQNM/zVR8ypWklaYNLKDwPL03TONqGCFcxOUKXjr2SazUhZPM5ha4c4/DgeX1SU@MrDDu5NQurySws@oAH6QcekSO/IvMLbVHPAEXBtdT026PRGKZ8@7aGw1ZaTo7LTihqyAXU6bqW02gl3TOdAOmMoG8rkSuGc5NQzlaCs82AdGtgTjSx4DRdtjYdv//ukzGELOSAKZ5WVIUuE6/k1FyCJxgaWaVWkrlEIwE8gGu0gBf8L/@1Glxr8s/3D2hpNGrcBHjp/B06Yxj6Di@Oe@g@nv0fPx7OW2/8Dx@7Dx@7Qxf@0Fs@RCZfnf2r1QXrzf@QtyJ7rVYhq4E5AXqDX07Og/Ufvv3R3//6f/j73/hExCu0xQ7/8O1vMfff@VV8fuvbf/@tX/j7b/0GdfmVv/@dfxV6/cPv/D65C0xg@lJH2rz8@seXn/7R5Q8@u/z4ty9/8Cdonf9/@m9Dr4@/NXMEM7pc@X@L/M2v/Oe//e1P/vqzj/72W5/97W/98Y8@@rpaUn700S/97W999td/@jUC9h//8Ks/@uhrf/NLH//oo1@EcPP/H//wk8jry7EjmMHl@h/cAS73/183XsigcbEHXb@wGZ7EWadbERpKOdfaAx7XIK3N6JDOOoTeZJsQCZ6yUuORAKXAYm583TftnogL/Gv85qiuySq/GZ70XSfvmg72IWH8erfWdQ36ne5qV7Twe@m43Y7Fy@X4quvgeXy1aEIfJI30Wb92SrfRV81aX8STXzxHtyF6x@1ORT@YgpBouLbr1ZKg8iZBzn7Xcm1KxWDe6boOyrBOzQQ1CycbtjQtV4HyiSN3tKXmiwIRGooMgifeSinbhX7Q24L@t6Jm18ytYrHSFQ3b1L2tfCWP3ka8tGMrL1f64vsPH9wPgtEBSEymH2zlyhABT0/Dc462SpV8HlgKz2caNMUWfoCYCRjC2hr0x6beFeCNKz98QS21KjT9Wi2Z3NIUVVAqmlziwsLOEOZUHSGnFLbkSjCPRrJnW47rZXkOv5Ma1wJW4ECp5@TcpgRvAnWPy1BAnKqTHbNvYn9Ea07ZlEZIE2CEoDoYO2DMb0odMFpgLG9KFhjHdU2RN6UxGI16TgFXg1EJ1gaxujVIE0uWwWxnkVyyA@UslC8qjuuYF1wlq2etM1pzlV6vd7FxlplZSGKbLj1Xryw9PwO97Uxg4aC2LwQ92zmLrVVhBoGrkHFWsGae4KL3gHjOwvU4FV7Nl/hqozqzFwt8tXXBbQ/NrqXj16@b8tn1WAUQCRnUBCTUJNxFxXPdoNIxe65nzgJqSiEKyDJ0PUCOv4iTa8qY4tn15ApzgSZnM7zG@OzYrnEcpkQ/CrksrVyev@CMEB2e2b1gCWUr2ciRRaVkg9WIFZp49oxLbBy8q9XrQLdnuaKay@fyqlYo5IsqiL/lXCFfArKRC3JeVYF55MqlcvECWq0kvUrQr8qR3bOoNVfodwVSeoWdttlokfSrR5Z9VtIExn5S6SqIS4lXXOLWwbtqvb56HC4FqsS7qlCvafkymDQ0qRoVqlRVUDVBUwRFw/9rDCr@3zy8Cn8VnxBLU7kjPIvoEUjxoMA45AEepxK45Mh16SazO6axIsTuQKfnHu16ru//I8Lc0Z1j5nXXYgffxl73dfz6mj@0gsGKEE9HQ8vxcafaPxWEvWEHMojcngW4Aw/Pdt1lAYrk6RN4HOy/ff8ofi8v9cP4KHlADjtLHmIc7e3s3ucK5M7jR3evvPIhuDx5sHfvKLYWmW8UNR@D@Pm9Bw@uWsNX7vHTg97Y9fDm7j1@mps9Yifcm8fl4FoMFDtTIOEDrSjioapC1ki@GBkUDrcF3s6Vye3QmC/MjDIa32MbDy0/3jnI9q5WuKNoN6JOsAvomAS/VmV26RAtPVkxHNlQimWOGxHHPSVFmXRd29bxc/C9NXAc6D7pmCaq6baNlIhJn7qe3T21uuYaiMaQRlnBT29jJrj7AGQ4NgaYAGhJeB5vFz/UjmsuOvbYJOMRWekIL3RCo2f1ByBpnLpRAK6j6wTuz3tBfHP@Cm52CFga1O2aj309OJfgdh7jAEyixPO7PH9fD3Sp@Iyg/DSoOHyQ5/s4xW37QbexMQb9bm0rVwI@vyvjwLtF1KkuKVIVsKgUzuvutrLRNvu1fEHZws64Jme2E/fNUql6Dy6e93UnC1wyW8GRFMd6Royqo1ZAuS9uENI0z@1mc5KrJpM1RSaVChvQ3NV9Sl2Vv/nt7//4z751@dXPLn/wGygAkruuZ@i4hh01cUL16lAhF@lAkFou5UtlTS1lS@VSLq8U8nlcGKkUS8WynFVkpaQUSvmyki3lyiC55XDZZL5cDNV5SdogOzaO4GWZyi5tVAC8Y@DXqDfpmJI4qHMJtoKHvEzpaZLQY/uY8CbE4cmO0zdtgIGDgQHdCrth1aDfJlBGrUgAsk4Mkrh3b1dGFN1BC65o3JV5vouWfEmWi3d43qQ@uyUUTnmXxSnhEYt8wCyyfAeqcMwA4FcFeH6Alr0CztDwvIWW3R1WFT20qBgfgh0zH2axI0sRgjlo0TQG4EUMDYLtsHRyNKN7aMEk0ece89kFP55/O8oO@hywYAzA/aikOzs8v88sOzvos0uLnWcZ/SJadujF8x5YoH3xfB8MfQ9aNs93wIitjOcNMBlTHdzwC@B4IL0T6Dw/ZehBBPH8hIbWjWOeb0fumMy7YW7yiN0KtSis1NvUUsYfz6tRpjGYFls0ns/FlhyU7f79d/VB0DX77Jp67G1ASe/f13RrMt6713n77U6/3/GmO3tvH6DX7u59kGimY6/T74QRO224XIi1e1/Vj4fTqxeUer/druj2Uq8vtts53bni1Z62TcwhxHoBOQuvPiY0bO@C1@799ra@ZNHThAJsI4MZwruD150hvO/oHeYVXdSLviedDl@FZgB6TDPFoeqFC5eweR4Dw3ayQ93w3CraJzUi06X000ZBblWpBxmC7iRXL9C/l8KnjgPu6bNpY1KTW7VJraiyYbZeim9O1LzFZ9eGW0o5X1nTtxQ1l5lUcBe/20uSpKBskZRye@MlST1Kb6mgQa3xza0tgW8ora1C8Rmytwo@tlSlVMnJKkkzq1asQBw5KROCj3Sj2Noq5iuzyMViRpfUSrEIsh/gJwAJooMj3G2SSp2a@nE6jVmnI6RQHlpwMqWFtqq91CQ7qbFMkmm6OqkpVXaKM5GvQEuluvhpgLGBR8gQBrQPACegQuG6uRSvlEs85EGScOEmjtsx5Jzl5NLF2Zl/dta8iFmlBKbZGPV7Xzo6Pjp6H7gViCRTNrRXD0d3n3gm8rxoFfzb93fF/ceRDU/9F@@hdOx64i7yuAUfJiZHTkegRYn3oV8HDTpygziB59riHl02DyJ25BEdvSOGJ/OKR/cX4BwO3FOWMkTyqyjF6Xh@An4UweoSvVYHk94lKZoroqdPqUTRrtdr7drQHI6CKRQxivVFQr8YMAOz77O804@04CfsafSznucOQ492Tb6odmqTxEQQyA4IeGMvCxDbNSIoz4du97maMapd/CrCndodBFNtw7tTNWum57keDyosX@1tObWx4@s984np4aEQ@4/XQdLBM1VSPWKm10lzD0PvomJ1IdQ94szy@Gg8TOlCvZNedMIZkdgB0ZT6UlT8M5wRgJzz/EW1VyOpZxD0Bdi9dZLqinfSW7kqYOwOaafBSX7ee94jKinkqlQPSiEsaIIUU4gBPV2rfxEENAb6GPpsyE1Y5ccAFRMDwFAb1EdPj6yLqlGzSUogkzTFUa7arzUw@jk@NgUQMQShcd7CCY33UDl4MYbOsw7NvTpN6DV/3KHfySFyR1HlQnUCbkoxVx1AfevPJlWvNhp7ZtUGazgFQmiJ9SrgFlAIYF6epy6/@lF6U8jXmFuVgjrHceu22K5Nqg6ecAqUUtNq4JFp5ORsvpSFRzELIoRayCqFrJbNZYUiuoL8QPdToB7WWltL2SmeED4rT2RRySqmkk3Jz63u83T2OIVSDUVeOhu4e854SNAFqgypldrhracz6gagqOsSfVOgxAtMporlAtwPyMjKDiikA1O3WYS0QLSNlL2ewkDrR@PRXqNVqexNRl8Cr5TwYquQKcqZl@l0NbWWrvnmCzpddMcCAtEBuciZaPFHa0DT4TQR8cfDBtQ6mJSiWmk0OljWopzVZA2KabXP@5t8nW9l5bWCAnV2QWcDFMI4y/zECEhO3Mxt1EZFwTahDpWyWuXoNpIEueON6UyNVlKFspTfyMtsdoSB4EYhi0TcklQz2nGTTCWTRTWZnGnV6WQVZ6LX@NnEINW16criVBJYNkneVvOFLR4EQL7Cl1Uegs04LuaSyFHON8iubvq6hzNIHI5VkBzo6mfcxdnFZp2biNze0LItPQvCrIEfnLOMY5G753rdLOlYfdLTA2zLIrcDpd2viNwhKHomNTX28KMDhMWnx6FgtFYIsEKn14LBdGCCNiRyUzrbGIjXXaGWCL6jpBZDkC9wh3iaxqb6DH/FZw93HuPv3nYCt6eQ7S@AXxncS88ePn389PE9emLCbCPz57m2OSLRPSgTsV1NVOmgPy7NgGSwaJXPsRh8GyfgibSGRwGQjCiIdXrcxDZLpRkefCStEfJ5N8lkNuvP2LuJW0EBNEdPPG@QFl0mblqop5N3dRAot0gSqlz3hg1V1VoNtQhiCXRdDZkFVVWlCrloJ@i@5jrQ9@QMMr2ZqeOhEl8k06meEaKi3yb1fmZdVqeJkzZfKGv03IN2XZGPyVry9gZ@ylsgiZPjtbq6kUk@qWiZ5N2klkucpJrr9YwyTUpkI6NOe7hIDZdDSUkIp5obt7SN5NNMpdTPVpQMPlV4VpJEWEtst7Pb6bLPUUomiQUEr5V3ajv9g51obf3Obr2kTsPDMBLP2nypGGaxuQ4oUzPPthfi10EWeoZTt1fq7WdZ@b@Nq@CT1WTiLEkSyYvkRSPZAtCNRny2Sq01yz6u6QsXPmi5AkknSDq0FcsJPxWvOvhCcjuRxKl94vuvgKBpPdBmHR178MXnKjCZhONGDu44wGFeEKPyeZy4TkjPR/4Hakl7uP/YuevdM7lEc@18zcVFCaTKM5A8eeW88yVQYaG2kqRZS0xquXDmV6nXBWVTxaPOiqQCAkBPKQjyeZ1xsjr1KKjgc/nV7@QmmyWwq7ICdlXNZ9R6XdkAETQxuvz0B4E3JWd77@48IEmcR/7xn31PLf74z36frp1PXtC5ZVUrJiAkGpVCMXF2Njo7AwHwgvnlE63EtXWALUCTpOjl4oZYrRCpVCpviG0pwdAJonJRSSd8IRHuqCjkhVRKkdT0hlaS0@BzHh4nlVLlElijNR7UiS/k@XRi78DKq8r25haUbEvLqdW1RoNX4uFwEv82Tb@c4BKlh8/PCQGLUe/2@5ZKTZIUtqFXAtl8JWzCG2r4lbBGntfquJhRwUNcouUCG3gABK7fSdYz0kaSgJ5N6o2L6kUrQ9cc0GGPZxtO8woymmu4Y3jRacOBn7nh059pUit18MEa2cyND30@tZGWpG6X9jm43kMQ6glGsm2T5OtALxsS5HIjWiLAfoLQTF9@9TdVtfDjP/uV8/Z5@31VVcvlckFREz/96ebYGftmt/5TiPgkOrgPiMiwukisR@6x6fhiPN5AOzrLwQ@OWU48TkHYmY9WGCs2iAbPJcYO6mIsfDRqgeMTBORRq@@YXTpawZ2gNE2rtc2OyuumaLANAspIlupy9GyudJXjIj2H6Wpe38hSGGQDz4dutNLcGfcWeuHWWND3qtxbM1DgMARpzDXavj32RnSndYrGU1pZchuiQApv4TGEaxA6TcI@WwAuDP30tagsyz7FGpW3CR5ljocagijCvQVRwvPs7SkZ6Z5v0pCWA3KCiEFoPqlHtwFptyBtm0VoU9cULT0LkCUsdyySAyoc9xbIlhQLFoicxNqEAFXgKW8BAqAMqRCw1SKbREuTMyuTqc5OTLzA83EcF1AYHenHYTSE1gU0xZGrGA6cQHXEj/YiXYQ1DHxvzjECwmCwBXw1UD4xOrWhMG8BOUzeGBTAOh1gDdGikdu3Z7mq1axumtASIfxja4SDtbQenOV5BWCRFn8LWCqIU5kMVvZbi2QHGM/Q7ALVCewQyupcVMKj9YLj4P/GRIsUeaWqqEcVCxDWF2sVBqAMIiPaWR0aZLNGFLWYJnHmDci7QTNFD3yKhyaak1ui@n7keQE5/Gki@v4WMKuj@QHwkG7vmvb58DxGuE9AARvTM2mDgc6YQde0rSGuDMThamR6@0EUO44FRbFsGrpneaAG03WC0UmIKU1JY7TZyZE0H3Q/o5ojuKswn8YXjYWhCbx1PJkvTGeNiq6GCxXqj1yHHuUXIGvCbZ1AEcCjIIFHbmCybI@dU/woXlg3NPJ8jqCUoOUg5WOO6dGErmP6LC4ut@t4pn4c4SZLzL5IjGGXqGWSooTm4LoSJwaXppFohjugPSGOO7Y5hCwdmiY98MCvSFIfhL5xByfFpYcW0NXgngXdj@NLdxmCpVPr2JKO8AB0we3huQgUOEABORGbH1uwB4rm2O4S23WPiW0dm2xeIzV/LCJ@Z6SQBcUnC5id3YDYCoq8qpbFQTAly0LBXYRXkRlL2bm4a6lp@vpbU9ZSbazRc9qDWVArtnmiO3P4pdc5Fw6k@FOfo6dA1ggqDimwizHLhZbJDlRL4hmHybQIuO@ChEXr14coGFPE@bJRik/wadEf2VZAjdzIM08IDoRw2McA0zTaYRawFUNp36IdAG170LLwZMbAq0DNZSAnXjdlQNMLGbxDbhFN5TAgpIxBWQYABlZ9bRE6@EFULIcfdKFiRDpJhHwFWuewC3548ltIfhg/om4003MyZ@RN1kJw2OnQtGqENYvIkp@zYOtAeqZFXwPPAuRwSU7WUnwGwGb4NM9Ax/GvRmfUzlFeUiHXIWUJQghRDVCoqKAjy8Fjoee@aoerSO7owJ3xwwVI9UD0p6enIj2EdOxZounjl95819FtadS3QBx2pcAcjsJvYVuGNIrgzkwC@5CjOBqMtiYo1NbKt6fszXE9vxauv00le34SO8cT/JBZf3iCuhVkuOdTgrpn0Y8dGqlwPTCjP7WVPYvor5KkJ/olLxAIIQhmkp1mjSwAy3aM42zvtFsNPU5ogwTgUItm5IhHA3uRZehHJmvUi0O4AfLR2KtjH9MFBQCJZ7MFs6RZCaOQ08ga2kcWLtx3zFOy43n6NEX90xgaCTg1pWIPmUK3T33@3/a@fj9tJFn07@gpOjgZkC2@HNvJYONZbHDCrmNyACeTixlWBoGZAcQgbMNkfH7nIe573Fc5r3Gf4t766JZaQthOMh9n9zdnz8RC6q6urq7urqquqoZH2GbEJ85TO1y0lu1Q9YVfHTY136UIFvIU7lz3AuWkxfh9wd8X8H3B3xdBo6rZ1qLNIhm@usPuINdjBIIqiWCWqswdJ/gNvhBkkMNFnkFgyWXoHfopd4tUW9Gbf8E4FhVjAE9MgeBOKtv64aJ10Z54zu1meys7AGZPECFgxAF0q000ve35z0j90c1o6nqhV7B9kHgj8cZX3SvJDcwr2Ed/gIgxmF5DTMo6GEtXJxYIZIcBAsph8BFFg9I8NTT3/SzZ9BEYp5UIaMyItSQybZK@5Cf5DsQlJj0TVgfU1gDhe79LgCZ8EWrm8L2eanX4MHOhjCqbpqsIYYlcimQ7CZSMTBVea/ZpkDSs0mmFJpAdxdVitCvqOwxFK/JJ6@adHH8d/aefjX4f5kU89sSwvGHsG/pUwWgDECHkdCGqisOiNq6AQXbTHjkz2LkqLJ/K3Rqa2cwqNYPbwS54t8N59yqlDX7X5PGhtBaJSaLgs8KyWIQuLos8LXleKJIywf1qnqy2VIwg6/MCAjBysdUcWW2hV1sUi7xwiMWaarcakgtCcsFVuPRiDZJtWQ20p6raXnB42iCdYhhEAuDleRsFMWiaEJ5946ALx4/X4ylqVarNYM0hLpA8hCI28lm3Hdt6S0NaW7QiAJARVwD0@MrvghFd8PJp/5e/RjEp1RrFvyQb8FoBDEZL8L7BOpDPZKQDg8Cf2KJ9AOZuYqtlJPJ0TID/y/F/CUu9VP/lV1/mwiXz4Zc5K/K/3@VlGymrTVBN@sjndnBBNgJLhW6yeOuCNhjYITSHCe0VHhSF38ECMKFirMGNEUqKFLd7zQtkX@ApzuyBH0mKClZOWKKkPsYLjZU49yi5NzUiKLHbLegZmCdlX7tfQFkZgo1RiJPqaUVsUsRLnwRnJTQnZgmWUhiNp8PJfQjQyR5J3jiJyGrx3CvAf4CDpUACmch@kSLamA/iRhS5vO63KDOWnAjEpyKV17FBBPugHE/waN1KPPdEwvoGKprIuJXaiWmEE/XLI5JQfUDOm05SUMtKpDMJqgrvYGnFd2YYBI8mvlcIA8oomypFDBUKvM0uQ7f4OAvoymTgkGJmZ/OvcnvfGtS7iTW3xq1v29Zmt5gQsATZk7F3Pbvt/TRwr276YiSmP14uustffhZid0dgFs/tbzgSM79XzFLcGEXoim9zdMWCRPA7ijXFFOkZZc5OCrpcgUMXngq66EGQn0IBZcIIl4rNseJCNCrMi@PWXrs4gUV43Jq099GsMd8qzrfyWyl88U3exBRKWDPVbc3bQJc7bRZtGq9t0Grwgk1RuvTo4BP2NCNkLpjDDunhCSwdXOCtS6MhCPrETLekkMowQVBWgGEDiPqt10a1j5o9lbfwSar3UCkjagj5dohCif/Bwzv6PNph8Xh1jjcGAEg86gIJgxL2wy77YpuVdkdgj7AU7NoDHQkccTTH4PT3rwHIGPJKBIO7Sn1B4xhekCxQccUTf9ipC4bxH9fD7k/Hr8V2Lvcyn3uR10iGt@IigrnMi51guwIiqQ/b6OKzm98xjGN3umSfPdjMEdZOGgFa4hSV4/eglzk3zmTiGKXRiJ37PLy5wpndOL2MYdSdHvmNXl4TRVCNu0ZygVbrXs@6fN3B5XBiz5bIF3gXC12QAJMf/6JT4hhUnb68BtAy0AoCCtl4OGdbiXszxGtFfMtP3x2N3FskWBeNLkwPrDR2YI8zNk0RRgmJpXAhfX987c1xSqPVGAHal3hpbdcnwwQ2vy6MDJkwjBGAIsOd1tikF8EE2uuObFS1MnEIQEMaBRQC0LXedde5FweDkPhMHITsmIrVsNXIZN2Z4dJcGduo2oJcFxCYRoWqabjDADffVBuiUTtpfijVKwKe39Vr76vlSlkcfRTNNxVxXHv3kTxyxZvaablSbwgMaT2unTXr1aPzZg1eJEoNqJmgD0bp7KOofP@uXmk0RK0uqm/fnVYBGoCvl86a1UrDEtWz49PzcvXstSUAgjirNcVp9W21CcWaNYtaVdWMoJ6onYi3lfrxG/hZOqqeVpsfqcWTavMMGzuB1kriXanerB6fn5bq4t15/V2tURHYMaNcbRyflqpvK@UMtA9tisr7yllTNN6UTk8jHa19OKvUEflQL48qgGXpCLZHbIn6Wa7WK8dN7FDwdAzEAwRPLdF4Vzmu4kPl@wp0p1T/aEmgjcp/nEMh@CjKpbel19A5I/UAVWBcjs/rFTyJQko0zo8azWrzvFkRr2u1MtG6Uam/rx5XGvvCOK01iGDnjYoFbTRL1DTAAGrBd3g@Om9UiW7Vs2alXj9/16zWzkwY5A8VvPXluARVy0Tg2hn3FohUq39EqEgHGgBLfHhTgfd1pClRq4RUaADVjpt6MWgQiNjUuynOKq9Pq68rZ8cV/FxDMB@qjYoJA1ZtYAGAie1@KEGj59RrHCfAix@BWQ3FuRYNp6ieiFL5fRUxl6WBAxpVyS1EtuM3kuYZdK7VBLQhXrzo2GNdaOuvvrpx0CFsVdqLl//886fjWrkiEurcMBF8OIdd51XkYEr/BjuN/xF@hg4Aes7l9aCDV@6gxO5XY6Fq7A0sTOlgYij5hXHPObWU3ajCxkan877UKdVfNzod03pMzRAaD9Wg1KogrN1TypR9xGAztKGhUFkoMN0PQoQ6/AbFwb4zswQ7IVNJpv43tLlO7DHoitlsz5HV0BSCgJVYCnvwzB0LANbDpZGssBj8HjRJUg/9Hkp2oIopBT7T7cBr7DkXcj34Z/Jr8IM3B@0FrM4sSmezA2fOaICCqprhRsjARP9I@w5oXyTJe47z0yCV05tzJj0zg/dToXekrENl585oNEiZD1S/dAaR6ulofUIWjZoqYbLHkQWsXSBj8jmYJJmQ45KZUc9S@E9nTn9MhQ1b0NBQQk2RCV4qRKlvuHor10aysqEQJGoeZJT53pa@r35AJTe3vbMfef/Gf89zCx0G0bcUNrwW1WvTnzdtLgATjCybQJKhtDdms1odEMtIoPQL30LBKyzE92vhXn3l0L4OJAFB9toe6W3ibjwbLnTsYR1@XS@9PTo/OYGlE7HdebX7cm/f8A8xv7f470dsh7w76Qx3Cvs4yGn0SZslxyD40EzRXPED9icGzmaxIEZyqEGjl2g18y@xYiGBk2CQLHWA3fUwE8QEzSAJZ0IXb5E586mh@DV2ZkoGSIW6amJvxvaCRHwbZCXiAXloOlrSqC3wH4TtT381xf0OSQaSLEb@rsC5xhNe9xJYiU7a@u71hI9BsEgmofiYD8V9GuCtXCJfkMeI9EvytjaKINjiQON8pWGnmoDE0ygWQuqh5NkNTbwjq61ULuksFt58L/kNHj9KdwFyHrC9eWneADKe@DVRBw4UXdnploTcxsg6PKJWLR0ItCCYEimae1JV9c2s2mwgVDDoFa1TYcD7vlU22iQqwsm/JUHfZk5FUyjC2ZccK38D58Z1R0LZV9ZY@VvZ@ATD8k3GTLVbvw1DFfnoWwUVOUNk@ip6EPw/kSYx8A9A4wToAbU0l4pHUZKgMq1AfSWiDG@VEUOznATU1F99DMDc6QNz5XdMWoYW5EqAJJCjs1QvPpITST8VQwBkchM9C7T523MdunYcdmZQnf6WMGV1tMFMuuNpSsi9Qm0VK3DTe22LxC5L2W3whylMMswKrcFTqCr@xorbJc16UJkiqrx47iUYnKmsqdlNPM8IJjxxKVIkryZ7wFk5OcvUOiAPrrQNp@efP4FYerfWIrgpNIej0NovrWqKUAD6EPFZ7SeFGLqiO3I9J@K/wndANMmnAD33LXl1onQAQE8DdHFCOM97Qt5K6MxvcYMYMXRyfAigidRz8r3ARvhYIhAc1HJrZoC0tK3e@tgvCPtbDfvzCceX0M@CUCUy7GMiMZzgtZLAM3RDt3hrLwHl0eO6zSyW3Wy4lrh1KIqHzRKyPkZcdl13BqKjjf0GHK3h0syID9Lo4Ey865n0BoH9bDiTFgkl9EMzKDax9k7bDMdtEGreEOSGOdpckD@oS2PHnkgHkeEivSdSwLyKRw@RhcmtZbGVF6mD4MsB0IScvIiIB2IPM6xRKSaodMByiIJDz1cuYJa43M6ByAXT79ad/YR7P4pAk57T8/28NJDwQg1SdUIeM905d33qemTRgKFAC4hPiTwb0i7t7k@3KHnDHv1SshMI6PgqEfgaoScY9eTz2/GZVELFhgLGla0D8@2lYTCRStvS0cp3vcpv7xIqcQrX3VpljHyvwiZxkbiY@EtKQd79@lyJjvjE66b/9BGf@O4/p/jcw9kDb9B@LkVQRBhlVrTZrq5zhB@eV3wYOrOebhMFSaZnT9H8RqqPOyFeVKZD6UTRteeeswQNoJsdLrIEo5P6u3s16Ry7I3swdIc26GkYWrHgFQ8fl/SIAzaYubceBRNz1iStUG8ZPJM1XB5q42/psYM/g4NOb@5MU/oRyHy2LGGiBdRi6Bgfz1r9/Yr4exo9cfbr7OwGlfw6hEdmeu1dgW66v7bui3xcZT4tQABygTuMnM7QMbmDPo9F1ZI7TWnHHarA5X0FNBwvRVrY2ue7tRh/CySiA94QxgqZlSMPvROoma3FuNVbWD3y6Ji5c1i3yg7GrHopem3ZmNMTVpHv8BSiIPKvclpVSpjZW6BXBz4s15N7@@WfjD0g8BXo51/EcUscI9AS15ezAdZkUiakzxbgQu7MQ1qjaSWGVWw4gF1oFALaWUShhj8v11GDThVBKJJOCytciTMyBYoP5rxIdWDJ6SzphvSkSJrkKIAiSIkuzFnHsI7OrLp/jd4OHnFziF0GF6ZjCTmlIb2OVF2gEmYDDMGcXusos4fqwzNme/uxoxYhYFESMISDligzlVCSC3pi823UczrWcmewGCci1JOnkklv7k6Tj6Te2rUj9pw7jtZdcx2RPkWYrQib5WaPSFtc4uNy34jiE2GaMMXoFBt4CNVXevbZPErERbGD863YWT5Ah3U0C85k/U3FH@8ez33cFG8wrFRtNP6UItzR5Wvff9/qQMc761cQCZPVqw6tGB1cMjpLftRARcjkU@nxFCLuk7hH6NEDymG7PaCdPj5riRo9gFcOZOpTyGUI6Ylu8PbYwXVp2s9AR1KmOp/yFylf4FxYSzrKy6cv0WUTPzBAlIqddGCHYgtuMFgRPqJYi36qg26BeVyJ4OmQfXaV55NE1CcYxThI4w6797Y6y3S@vc@QFj4k0Cr4mvZ7IMlXWKzVWRCUFVLAFI8hhd@jlbXp6vG9@tq@QDmAwLXps3eNR/AgTWFnTLEF2MA/@qfOAmXgoClZMzSjwhOhQ0sDzAXQUgYjh9VVlP6GM@Z4vJ1HTiNQIPg1XSi3JWugc/Rezqc2Vln0lljElOTm2WZiojSqEjAU/0byy6nIoi4prgDAYYyhfjEPENBJjLDHQ4GR05@HOC@EqBwjqFjM47SEl@RjFviQxHxHosoCO7taiVxciW91GOlYICBYxJcJEAGZJb5IAAU2ulhctBIv4/sTlACBWPE@UxyGQo5KmIb@yDEBKYlezgxWlFZeWDnJwfRxZ9cMffT5m75@m9O@5qJfgT4@hq10Pvr1VS70NdTs9na4aqgm0MPUWw19BFKYOsL@qvB1/2eQS6DmQK4k3ANNyQhJGdL3C5McgpYJelvmR08coInjUMkYCh4dxqXzpCoq9avDAWshF/f73dlFko4M0BP@q3urYjYUJjLyInkxIUd7Nu6yQkgSawK3euwWarrkTYGGE/I4Af1W6bRuX7xvnpzoSrC4XCpHo7Ez283lcsjEl3oogfLbQlPS0M2GS2f716NRdnr799n7yyyt/Zgue@S5BaVBOzAkMCm8jDsbcJwN4gBFsXQaCDx2bxzU9a/7fT2gBU8ocfBg2Lgk@4r1BG1AQ9/p5X2Tg@tPgg32n9hB7N8/hT/7bm0WNCUUdQwFtYF6FzcJdXoG5MEXffT98k@qCBguzMqbCfYts3j4CXcQjBOjwSJnUBPNQpL9E2@c0ci1xAdMR/Y0QRaVSIWTE71CjovgCSMSBV2MRsBhlnBuhqPgfMrDIjqvIzi1MamoHeVlj5EGdWdQWUxTidYPCdhWoMtb2M0t9Pa1RGKQMKXr/SPAMh8C2o8qPbanqS7RKVoYtno5g4MnwOhF3orVfUJFTLKJSZo9XBqJGo9u5kd3OElB102SBVRkAA0v9WRNcZ@4iYtFvo80zDEMiRNdEvioGnf7X7c0ft2yeDPv9x@3KlJQBQ/sZ62IHFf2dQsinQHQDJTTD@iJ0ZX/SMO0PokEQrGAg6FPq@sOVuhgBcN43i3@fJsqlUri2XRrS5RKR/CASX6OSqKML46ORBkzqODvb4rbu7v7vOaWzU/w8ki9vBNHAIPvIu5ezcrwE74VMcANtnvSIp9li8@s/Wed4sHhvpdtlY7a2ewAnvhyqWxJ/sBbp7JH9KP1g18ok8lkn3U/Pfvmbh9/t8rt5LPL1rNpOznYRy4DMpSu5251nrYD99HM7NLY4F1Ae0t@pErP9jCNq6wqVHqEsT37CVaXgtjoetkN@dbjOFxaYze6jvbemWASFFDhVQhHVJU3MER@bC/RHA@j03XQAQ/2G8rhSn6gXJ/PVpThfuJqBfxTlQ1CQMqsNw6AxhOOJXSSG8b4Abxs2ZmgBfyGZF7unmHY8Hc470j@zf4gL33YvEiJzZzYtMRmIkF/8AKIzQvzWXaIF4twMf9qiOBoAd0MhTckQY/0B4pcjJDbMJ5RACRCUuHQVHhyPb5E47PS/jB8UoavewPjCd2PySYSOmTCKhufnk3uYFg@QYm7hPGEwhnzmPeDBYWO1GKoMe1ExR9fFIFsjx0BgpbHTJCCC03iSR9U5jO/rHojx9qg2EwCjGStvz6heY8vYC96RjGd@YguhUGjFPzIb3Fv3OfgXUIbv3D7AQJ0oMLqZI7CRpIbSTzroLsF/F5SNwXFeOr9k8zHvg5LZ44Vg@b/U2hMQJ@e6IR7NqF3dI5JH5n@iaF/vKI1leCyFG3PJzOGVmV8PZoPpyN55kUkwpHzW7vjmYQjSoAYDkdQF1ZnGBkKMPPBrUNhyPqwcOjxUvRc7DrPBJlrFaeDmeGTI40I2R9SMLd/jcxtMztETBQ7MA8QUr4rX98ejjwk@VwlbR3Ys0vMtUAJmsVwzudmZM/DnDoRjN2@j3SGIJPLeTCfoSsb05k9GNuW2DhzmzN7WYVtCySfeTdjQg8nyTkhgZNPNh3XPYUw90gOCVHE7wp5DmH09mgpg815bHE0aDBoSNVUkAkacBKE2Iko6fwaGqsIHQOu/oxB0FFeWbz900i5xNLKi55GElLQBfiHptnK1DFUC/rc8SdOwmBU/ZmpeEFWusaNdkwHv7CSY0Zv1TbVdOT5oIDlEtvH3WngTOzQ5jQdGQYnJnmW3Re8L@J8psQe7I0kLyzKv8wH@QMQK5AjfwgluJGZLtw@y2zGk1TqyYUng@M39H0EheeM74uftZFV5Vk5hYOPKSHf@WTIi2Vkhxoy7YEJM6JKnv8AoT@yB4Df8tZeIitebKS@e5o1Wz9cTNqbqYvJrxe/mISJXJLVLpsWG/IwW61Ycq7Azpi1Qj@VV5oHJMDcieJiEi5wMSG3Lj69lyQARLKp1g/Z9q9ZQOhiwzQ3sxcbTJDQkCEm2fvbyyL47AqaG2EsshvGE3PTVIOf@i5vCthb6S@OIb8w@S9goZRKMtODnjPrAyiKAaLLCVCxy77azu1s53dAExo4i/TMucb9Nu1dXzoLECU8VGdh67n4JcQNIULcLTx7H14uoJ/DwQTzQNOIejKhhVxC5TSndgyfraBOhnkCygOVU0gCDHEx/TI2Hj6iwm8JYDlVljJasOugxn0p3D89d4zt2B6ua9HoEOZI9DJgHxEyoaYRsmS8tRxqqumSpGCzjDi@cmCQEQgMb3ZD2y0m7iQthTUzk9xHIRqjZkaY1zc6R1emaGiGPpPCVPKpyB9@9/K//3ft5435xuF29sMM/s43ft7Ye7XBj/AAv16oXzcbhxsHWGzvbmOZBR0YHl/@9/@B@od/Bzj4ZXkA/xzuKlh7y43DdJGq/LpxuAcP@e1taPf//td/QR@escaGmW2edSxBiO0rihzbE@Jd@C6q2EtWS5PBspLHhQVhsIch6ObwAx2jFtuvcmSm25BeFTfo/jPsz31/FLnFk2PWnFyF2JKh/ClAMuIKRWwgzSCVC0VfaL4bym0DmTdAU/zzeWbPAw3gn9Kdw2/Sd9147qHL0DNWi2AAU9wi6PP8cJj7LuG7dxQSyqdkX4mQqNrJtfbVi31gh3euMx92w14SarqOu/atc5lBPsw4vWvQqSbeyP1xlr0Blhznt19l@2jcz5Ifd3ZKkNLTZeYXEARlNhJQDMnp1BIzGAF3DH/hGXOUgEB/4p9JqewcIGVPnS7bsMIZnqBIo1mu1OsWHw9jdzKBKJ2if0GAxzwkMq2GFnl@MYGatXpBJLb8glyOdF4TsXlHzrEy6UiavWEpey0IMNQHtA6q/mRKswEFIVGtGUDgIhm71@vY8lvKeJJQgeeW8eTKGU2LCfINg97gtWogoUv6s5i5Fkp6iBaEdJoWOoQ1duY2qOjFBL1BfTxoYY7XE/BZK@nGtLr4ZO3LslKr7xVP8EzrnqZvuelbGFGUEoJ2fJ4JcuFMhF6M15YimipnTgeP1GIbhtY8lQJrlqE/iIHHw1LtY1iC7A5FQALVgu5IrzJ92CzShYFHbh2O2WPTIucBMzaC4EdLlQDOqp5lUHbCdjPcGCwQZ@7EKaCHMl9/hxEQRZW0ZTghAWjls4odlmCoD7Wpw2gqQmFHLLktTWA/JIEDYykFkGDoeLypBT7YBu8ePmgJR0vok0DDS8JEluoXSNmigmo4CpRUixtHzYztVK2u8JP19GUuILrYDV8kcvntFzu7ey9ffYsx409kb@PBYKUMagHTKxtgkESdAiUb3xeLiWSCX2FCr9UmEXocWDyAQ7euW5Ow4seneJMAA8slCNYtJabi6tJcSSADiDMngzsC6CipWSKV@q7Qwo61L3rmr/BfwlK1meHQ1GyPhr/YTHptHN5xQASlORo7Y3eGx@O4MNuU2QVz6sMWwl/0so7brzt4aRX6ujLbQ0OnrotBCTP3enClc0eGrf2iCRMGCD6fLQukQb12OFKUdGoNK5RFpcGhqkVfFBW81moP0CkXtwSU@Rg4TDOYDOjlb0tPU5wdSdiEMM8DRqziEaLmOqqzM3HnxBWVs3IUMZkJbej5cDO6ZysId7AfAvhK7QQzH2ndbQJ1YUoMZK/VmmSxQZ90X7nA5bAccAUyPcZKdzGtl0YVtVaT3DBP3UeWPPHi0E9oF1SFcUS8YmDmcw@TUsW1ql4gQdRCKK1J/iJm@ec5OskCnPRBxnmKvJwoaD6ib4eeR7m8ZWMJU3qUUiEYSI9PJeIAot0ml@CO5Ao4ovRYoTRWPNp82yu5TOIFqTzAvqbqxJYc9qWpgKLGObOITwvsf/Xs2BLlCvxz8qFsoaB8VPoH9ttPmLUe37zEN18Q1RM1BERQaYYjn1v0mfoZQ5SAWXIWpy8JEMTFlwwbWI8kb6RgpXoiac@TuhWa2@2AK5BdbSmEK@uonCSYNYVsIE@k8k6mM5lrUSr0BTZera40W7KwmhZs4rp/Yms0eRK06kNiUj4CxHYURFqBCLj9ScDw7IFOkrctdRfF2NWTeJ4OsSwrVCC2n2SB7GGeXUuZ@9hiW7LFdgHH8T6@IL69lzf44rIwczzAG0@/jDfSj2eO9L8Fc1T@HO54IbnjRQHXHuaOSXfm0IpEEZ2U1M6N4ZjLJe3Bnd5wMET7UF/7iZ3IWRoAWvDoPjKb4kHyOezbmuVEpOI/bEX3I3QS2t7dM76w8zuy8zsFXHPpsez8T@18@jfu/K7s/G4B95qYkZeinQx//e16HIiEqfCL2OFFcZeLmV/a0z3Z070C7qYxw/yH9zT9O/X0pezpywJmTOADB07hej83syRSahxXq4G7RUZlIE5hVsB4rjRR98I7sS3RH117V0WU1sUX4/9K4v8KVyN6qiNZbS1G2dflWT3lYHmWLPnWPAyy4p5wf2Wol95fuWEF@ojcoHiRJsPWTCoqIJBb/DE4bcoE8mOw@vqbz2Nx5rWdcitxZlhNgWaNMG8GU5wlXyqsErA@YUaeoyXtuFk/3fpfTIax/ZOMQgPkcWhv8Y4huZPoKhiOFb@WndG6g7AbUucIsYokJyE7l9HePrs8Wb@qUWKLyL4YryTwURunS8YMVI7mAUQmI6BNRtZXWhW65ir1gt9A37lQfJdlj7@IS7@VXPptQdSlYrCOVLY0@EleDPS07d3d@/YArpXBPzgBcxaUv2dW/b/gcGHV/aPUR@p03jqet6ElizL0PN1cRmAZES5TuoYyswJeFzO5RP@D937yqW1Dy7YMyopnGMdvyw20XdiX3Z7TH1wNf/xpPHGnP8@8@fXN7WL5Sz5hGCo5f8rkrIXK@0aaKVbzNSdmiUjS5rSWtTkAgYb5JFtNwoaQZD6fNFuFwnbbFDg/x5yPic8HAgAkok68Ed6RRG4WfvZwGkr2YIjG9np09O/NMeYcSJYa2ePLni0WBYH@1@m8JdAbTL7tAiGBRGSHSXVh9Zyapkl3wsgrJ5I65ELS0n/qXZ0NxlW2z4lEQqIEP6t0IIDGFr@ob6FpkcmlLTaB@fjLsBe2lLBNxq8pU@uhWiD5dHunbRaATB/oCzL8lT2a84lg6hfT94Rx5n4kAW6dx7zI4S6SM0OBCxrSB7QB@h0zJXMEp1zcX21dDX3X2vFhtALw7VDhEK20H1sw9f3QHQAGU8E9ct3RKY6vasGS1LDEq6AzQSZEDGt@Y4/6/iiobMVDdqoM8U64j5RDFqkdGpgIISQx@v5KFwRTX2GzrrQU@/XxsAEwviR3hRVQOr5YaaXACpfQGhrK6UObRrQeD68353TiMZ0ImLPlI0E5ogN@095viO9rdRj9G3s2RMMWW9vy0EbGycD8HJDD/1xOpthERXJybe/CvPIh0wwzV5CL79M6lFOrL0HvlS@xAVp3sAN4c67qAu5mA8pu@DDSj0D5nukc4lAGi@x9AtuRz96KqfN7UqhLJhFpKT/GTbswdyNrz9DHOPUqMtiKDji99pBc6kWb5ZXg8yscZ8w5BnvAzGZ3sg1xPh/CIr4MfJpJuCGHMV3KoiREDIxz80cncPfKEpfyh8yvIzHVFg@kDeXpvzKDRONrOqeAtdgdY0u8xDN3YggfIghwOAPyZtyKiI35P7Ni21zfXSiF/fRWBctIl0ODGt9d91pHIPdgP4Py6gn2EH0dXyHEsB1mgVUIaqmVrsO4N8hPq5yNR1KdDub@6XQo1Uqng/JDp5PkVliY0IQg7d6L0mXvepae2Vdj2578Pdv1vDTeuj2dG0YXyHpwIJKVs3ISQ638T5npEsYhvZkWMk@/IJED3xiJRDjK9LjREI3jevVdU9A3g8ak645GjhQPpIxUm/XwftDysDtXYhNLeerX2Ma0QgZdSCmOPa9BuHAPcXA7HXT/73RSnjPqa6OzETzBf2@ab09FkxIONisNyofYiCmKMDIYAEnqKSJ@8LRcO25@fFcBKo5Hh8aB@gOFDqnewXw4HzmHB1n@y@@8@RJFgeXUAS1QvsvSS6ib5coHl25vCX96wxtBn4oJdfRfmDkgbg1vnH2orNOWEOy77jxAMAv1EaiElmUEVQW9MghytXJNFITdwyMbEASV8oCTysPAkGF/KZIvkpmhR3p9ygy3LG8@kdJokn9msMWkJZK3W8mYrT88EI03JaDl69PaUekUM369q9QxjeW6sbgcdIBpUIKlaxmS4a8cnuZOQkIFfZlLiTX6MVzqexKNw@8@ht@t6Ua98rqK@RzXY84kLYpPuUL@LvzpBn2qYr/QJRT07W4VgzWonJyWXt@LBSp1K/sefUULc@zXNU3Vzl7XMAUlps5c16I7GYCmMehgyzHkVZ@x6Q5e1OE9it6q5aNa@R6aD0bcmWij2BhOj0c1dVw7P1u/OEgX4XwYyobhI3refHfeNMI1/cUKJgytU5ZYaEuVNrWkT8rCXAf/qNSoiMopZTzVPpGvy8gZK@iWWFq8qIAKSmun44HoYqlEhSjGFKJxzXStauxyZF@C/nw9d/YxDrTw6W662J@7U/mAUw1z/BY41jX16a7nDMz9C@PTXYLbLiaAoROHn@54sbqYJPkqmnlKIqpP5hW8faRNI0KMcqVefV8pK3o0tM@hkkC06rH66tOrO5x1MW5Ooxjln7Fk9pmYEUqtbML0hSjPEJIEginDYPgZ/a4GM/SqTdMkh7f7ly5ufrAL94bXXmE393zfp4tEZKU5Bmnpi2Mk6XqMnKA6jN5lf2J3f7POUV8Qdv3eDoFYC1rp5QgTV8B/o9@9gxeGHNFLdz53x2lKa62Gl2uFvuNkCn32AcDkWl8bP8ZUjfbkS8i9QrJH8ZaaZpTa@aR6zJt8A6T@Ur1e@9CIrIYrfGnPZu7t@fT3YU2RU@MGT5KCtIoJpJuAdW3YExcGrWJ0gd3cn5dcSysWU4iHUpa6MLiczuyoSxAmZnabLiIMfn3VZCaild3byb8k2XD3@F1pFqZTHSv9cYQKencPnUKcs5ZQGs3/cO46hbb/JYmms@DvRLX1ax6lbL93zQsEmGbl@2ZUaEHy073UOuXxxZcRfHX71bsWCITUwhr2kPj6aMerb/es8P3haLRO8PVVvMWqvCwlyjU1NfVvsU5erlcatdP3FVGuvq42xfvS6XklIjbP8GzoxuGDbNnUzBnghRBAPzqh0hpOagpEF0MrKA6Oz7Eo2A1Pw9Fm1PcNmpboOxwOMpwnPS5r6BZVP9/PxJ04sS2pJgK9vBCX4ikKGqolf02i9Yq@hOvc4u2gRQlXHgj9mjSjpncoJt16kmiY4WAJ8rbF61bxHstVg/BI2tB4lEL0DSiLgPNtc3URunps7e242pIUkaNCkGiuzIh5Ptw5DxS71c5tr3YOCPZV3ZMIol0rA42mAN79mHVd7w9HDNp8GDHQCv9oqmFUS4hyZkSXXz2hIBeEdVwiG27RLAifhsmgt384S4qkWgvjTE3alRUFlrUH15PHTFH9HDU4SF08RSXeWpnA5kNT@NgdrQ5Zfm3/krPBJej0Fv2/6e8isWfx1n2XXMQf31trTvXvA2TeM9yxS2FkU6ielSvvKmd4JY34R@Xjh1q9jCbhRnRrkBe/R4bQ98QmE6qn25x1A6uqwMUoG8XcVfdEgRxzJUZuF2YFjgQZy2gnXgRHjQyeg1/gQd68HDopVgfxtEyQOSMZpsYKDGYTsbrO0zEzdwjB7azyA2XSvG/ycnW8nmKl7vKRdfMxdTE//WPb3l5T/7Htv4irT5ZZNhZJexVixH@Wa4Rof73UhwgNMOsG6P5JvjJ85u87gOLfbwTJ@vWV46eMTn/UIL76axD9/7ucPbLyTlzl0SMr78ZUnj@25b24yo9t@eVaxvVNnavca4moxe4z2Fna3f5akf6kFUnZPe9blOIHDe1@fw3bnzlsZHn9/IEjQ@RfI/dnjhzbgj9/6NAa@tfI/ZkjR/bor5Pg0BAZGUQykEbxQ9U9il24HXavQLsmAQh/vE@ERItmBIXAmumkHkEm87GNoTr5ZQrhl@p6X8po7LSDVm9pthbKY10yVqG9rtdh7433pVPxtlaunsR5cKwQyHP@sCm9TYq@T7bAkosfyfsmzmg267Bp@dFUFbFA0EnQH3MM74@dZOiX1FLF22Qblu3HuFqzv6xfz3yE77P03L2duRh/7uENSyrEe2zPNQ707SilMl6qfFo7r8PA1hufMdF77u8zsO50LR3ZxPkl3H/DDvpqDYxykr@48qSO9kyWQszg81Yy3kFbM3VSLE1/5NoBavQWk9zz6xXTb7iN9Ne0kX5cG5tf08bm49rIfk0b2WxcI2uWpXLl6Py1yIrGm9qH@DL0xbvCC6LwdqfuzHEm65aw8BoGdX4fXo@1nP9pVsDIDuGPhj87IpUetN/L5egnkE78eyz0RUgbHB4@Hp3hRKVQftTw0AVof@D4fM5@ETdGTBU@pvhN6bnGFn9WO0uTAT5kiOc77H3PVt0k73mYJFBa5T33etbVz1MoNS2OEX8JMtOmViKn7t3B8DalsAMth/hgnJfK90Chr0JlEuW7QeL5lh1Tt2DAYxsJ/HC/phHfy3WlndDCpMQT4s6LSfxmEt/32MUy8HZurTgAt1tJxCjZVgxJhIgFs6EDSqfTWOVTkhk1Wfh0BzIhgYLHu/V4xHgAx@Ia6/W8UnK9L/Mq3wfNm2sJujLOsfAiISc@8FXXaXNN/Jg/EWSO5hB7yHMkujxCv0iicO@R2yKUyjlcWyQtPZJnLTn5OC2QNS2xgCUI/41b8B/tMh47ER43wPGO4do1ZXSZsLF2HtFyP1KHqxsxcykWRrhanMSGJ79A8Hhqr9kcNb5eCUYkjpBaAJ@xrxwn3sf5VDWOrR849Y@sD32lWAQTG0/P/amdTN6tWRt4jlF9//IEpIoFRDfj4hR13A7XoUZIkLbjSbqAnrm@JBbS4pVS5trpO6WscwH09XNL7sRTpMqZO3G@gIT890EixnBgeAL7/ib2io1EU8r4aJvEijSJFRRA5J9xU3ZCQvVreTrMruvQYR2xJOqVUlk0mnVxcn52LKpnjSa@qJ3Qh9PqWSXmVGcZPyz69qcI3lLUbgepHx@98oYB8Yb4r7QKkzavCC7HXnq6EbP7Y/8Alz8wx4j2oWitOMqieBlPWDVChYdpEF@xBbDbgSI@bN8LaMg5Mf4NuCCeGvfzxYPagKYRTFzhXWNSL9xMnAXoIF7SfOwa1Srs8LKEe/VvtFNqAkLsTrle7IhZjOKk5TX2PHUlxmcMHJOQ7oOPkS2kmqluyTDWzjsqkF9j9wvcnOSCEPVwCg1PRH8rHcGqWzpuVsribaX5plZu@J8izrwYpxuN0l0NfdNCcM1IcH7y0hlcT6IxphT6Nuk9EjLHzsaGtWYoV1N8yGumO3KBRisY0e3vybXResel09PS0WlFkiYasLdwulKPxZy/nak9v4r2gNVYFXHrF4PdfpaMZH95lYyip0OIdIsGI/IupFvLepEiSGjTeCjynOPFAWk/Xls2FSTG0cplmA5BahvTwMyihoFcINJdkc7rAelPtahjuk5Hpk3n1xamR5o4tzTVbD8prfE/IZD7keGVORldmYsLrsxRbCU79VNI9H4QY5k43Mntynjwh@LCmcQy1VE4yF9M3dFyMHLhGR6A4tmec5OdXI9GBm75vWG/Hx4E/fnwm228EdPpXrkCsPn/)

Currently tested with [Python-3.12.0rc3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/Python-3.12.0rc3.tar.xz).

Same as 3.10.0, except now uses (non-minimal) perfect hash generated by [this program](https://tio.run/##bZDLboMwEEXX@CtGqVJhQRveIQWy6qYblt0gKiVAUucBFSFSpIhvp3dC2kVVC47HnvG9YxdP26IYhgdVF4dzWVF86krVPH8uhVB1R6vMDnNK6Or4vkmOvwACjkKbETIchmuSa1lAiBJ3gYTHS8/C0rM9wOXICwBW8QLOzv0@otmMDlWtl6rVm5M0eLakFFV9PtKVUrjbkHt9e0eUGjb10djbcaVqXYqr0DZNq/POPrEi2sfJ4j6wMAwpNJRonC@yMI8Q/9SrBE1ckn1EKg4BFKNG8YUvNCWbszSDvwXLUWKdpbf3sPo/QqyR3jWQYUttPWrpeEYEH9AmncPl0pePc8pJwgUXY6lfrR1r7WIF3JrHUBt9lErgv8slbZuuobq6dHyyx//V4uhGn2TT0vzvyycm3K3cLDKb4TBchsfwGQFjnkvWbKvu3NaEe2ts84K5F70Yhm8) and adds Python 3.12.0 with `len(dir(os)+dir(1))==475`.

```py
# Pure:
import os;n=len(dir(os)+dir(0))
print([9,12,7,4,18,1,-420,17,10,8,11,2,5,6,-424,0,3,13,1][(n^[2,3,0,0,2,0,4,0][n>>5&7])%19]+425)

# After fixing DOBELA n_, Whirl 0z, Affine Mess 1122/2, Retina -424m, (…)[…][z]:
import os;_=len(dir(os)+dir(1));m=-424;z=2-2
print([9,12,7,4,18,1,-420,17,10,8,22/2,2,5,6,m,z,3,13,1][[_^[2,3,z,z,2,z,4,z][_>>5&7]][z]%19]+425)
```

Comment: This is absolutely bonkers

Answer (score 2):

## 444. Python 1.5.0, 18900 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPZdSD4UdHp@RGXCVYBIJBvvEGAZLFYXWzVSySru90ACpVIJIBsJjJRmQkSKJIV3RqHVm3JHluWbFmW3bK8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsanm84djYBDLzPs@999xzzz3nvrKj@4Of/SyBF3ni2tO@7QYkMP2AdD3rxPREcmdKtnXLz6sax2GoHa8/HppO4Fe4BFEIsXWnP9b7JulZdmB6WeKbJumYtnsK/iohm2Nn7JvdOtg0QhzzlOw7htUFCCRwj03Heml64Jcj5K5pnw/PA2K4w6HudH0y8iwnoL55Qp7oYOmNjWOid/zA043Ach3wKiwkUVywlQh56Hq@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@lDwEbXpDh9d/8J8Q3XAxvcGJY1rJvAGHpANjdJcu/R3SSpx9Uieh0urqIaOYMqSESe5ES3x0Ah8zXhQv14cWwOqyy5lqyQJKBFlUkuR3LQfktEzQOSFLkMBmAEqqbAXSBqieQUaG95okFgTYXGXQAfaBAkJ4NjOZnF9Hue3rdsk0HvI/QiNh@IpsJTzhENWoZW0Fjovmv3WFCDZqRItBIpFEkxT4rwLJOyCjnBZHPQaPJwF@AGiGXIJgBSNci0rDJgs3YBdIy0uEt6@tCyp2EKNAmD5BVSBKhQHgWgqyWAAm9Nw1uDu4TQFq952MEAamOgnwB4wbaOkZ2ZMUfDKpbgJW1sSJR1Im9myfsDTB5QC0jNl0gRki8ARnKQBcC8WoLkwVPLQxYghJYvQME0uAuscP7AtO0Q1MBHULQERRluKE0R8FOCGoOaUGVEdBFusANHVYF1qsAnVWB9KrArVQWzhslCOKzCAlR/IceSGej@MSTE0lG7tFKgOwAwCtYCskkFEQcQoCYJoF/DjJKchsQDmYcyQV6KBQKEUVJIKUdKRQI4LssE6kyBfCFlKcChFciPgsCANhQgDgXypEANKABU0fKEm6sARUN/iKtBXECXkoM4OTBDZSoFvCEeUIwCSSqQpqqWZ4QLeVPzUN68RilaLUCNF8EP8KZCXlUgMyRjtQT@GLcEOCwhwReTWYYIHfEANYVNBOgTkAHVo1C4EBbMajEkaN0eDfQO9gcsZqeHUQvYdAqIRogqY/HgnUNsQlagllVsIZB9FahCoy0M3rk4eVsBIA0Eb3YtytRt7FiUGEPFLCXSD/VRMEObUqA5Gk2DQeymMjcXmK0FDNPs68Y09oSWmY09Z64FDV1Vyp9ngOQcuvrAjd2xb8@AxIacSpMyTyx75laibl1T7/Ysf/BqltccTaRj6oFjHc9Syeezc0jV5zwK6LHgVNTmwwaWAF1cf4CmWVnUIoYZuXEFLWRZUWj2OmZv7PRNoVyayx/1CcZeAJ3RLM0yc/asfh869hkcJUuLSTvXmXOe5tDWNOjzI0fELqbpWdDl3ybGAESW2LPM4JfLMxiaijCmegclAQFEOOg5ytjX9awJ6dw2aE8zy6BG8WQMrFEUuLIy8Fzl0kQmpcIcbVDMvSzJMcvGqyV@6FpOKkmSae6Cg/6JiaXzvTt0gu9hz4Z9NZIu9MUulTRmLDXlRL1pGpC2KBhAT22jANUxDR17bezDTNoHR3CsQCSQCMiWpnuCMi/tSBeS8Wln2/FQxAXJqGt6HsGwIBf7Wdot@@OOb74Yo@w1y1cP@nkTxIGebtlxBmjfogdUaIB30of0povZ7nnukHZAQ@x2bdcdrRBxoJM/RUD33VNzlvWZDKCPRjZIWuBuMkEPMnOqU2GdSvbzqbIMQSSMBxUOAGlSIKFYnmlQ3IdFh9gayDKLWawQtX5bQyh35kQwDRoLiCc@xnHGtl0B2cg0iFaXuuaJhC5MTFsUzzAPkeAG4lcIoqODNI45p7mIId1WRSoSHkU167vDxaKxPnc/LvrAQmHKPtWnUHs96G7NiT4EnYGgYA4tlwyBYlgNYk2AcoHF2idd10kGMZRTDwRfKHRcEipcI04Ca2iC6uRCFKzxHM009vg0Z50pkDLFVk6kuhLLyRVEidxVRDGH3JwDaywgInbHBmIN07YcSkEgQvmoF3jAKpkbF3ik2dTh9kAGHIXqoYgGDHiIWZvTMnzW2kNp3aAQUa41HR8UF18kFipvQPl9twfEdmpB2YFhQdQZbIMiAVEQO01EQ@QoypGAhsc2sYgxGhFwh04JyPOeXAKx1f3QIi/B0x6A2mGMPW9KJiOoCWsIoQLD7fWAel@aowGAIMMuMaYGNE@oZEo9/sDRR1zXpWzGGC0WdmZbNyGMg@rM7pNfJH0TkA@ibg@VSST8WTFGI1oQihDdYWKwowO@sCDGaEqRwyVmMXquK6J71zV9SjKudxwzAEzMN/u0gUBr681Y0hDFeqBVh6ojXeA/YSND@Jggt7QwmFRIC2@bDjQgA2gTmj5UItbsDumBnj4n3KKGohuGOQpCanEpU7OcOU3h8T3UFKirEAIT/QG3vk02r9AOBI3pZ07KRc0Jsz4KFRgdOW44GCBQ8SNWVhl/safXkocQJ1dS559jmIUcPOdX5GFEGwaqTZRVjANkKMgjLWOAHDFAnkMlcWhz3vh68cFtPnlvSIRenDbmRgHmw4lS7IT5WA1DgNu@Dkgc2QirvuCAQRccXgNa94dLILtxJu3uvKso6SKwxtcBHbqOuwQqIDOGi0EWfWhdUGI8RN6h2zEx0ubiL9QRsu3Z@BR2Z9CTjkauBy2DsZ4pHYOgVTZHXaHqnop7jLRI7ix2sNBxJLHbD7AvhAgjWwdawCaGLRV0Lh34BbAyploD53NZinMZpq2ewgrzd0o7AEZM0KM6jolqm@5NGRAoHnTSkNCUWJ4HzPAEuwrWE0VdikjpFHoGvdtF/orooO3@auIiUvTuuGNNrurvBjqKH/rcie6RHqruHoge0IhSyZ6fTFepO40558VL7iiQaFT25CEgDSRClad6vohdxT1gNIdTx0jxC02MzxJ@HPRKfBoMGJFJauQdUBiu5g6VCCSa4TG0a2qrkj504oIATwHdaE7QQxLRQ/dA2oBGCLpmudzt6OQcuIdHhMkuU0gixUQRc3FaptON0woRgXmZL6/IkvA9gxqEub4NS4DBaclpJ7GAwDfEBI3Ig4MkhT0sOlCZj/lR6YY5jh063kdSTCBJk7NYBIYOIEUzY4EIYhlW0A6Fltu3I/FlrVYDYgOZCthmNz2v10ZjoSJwaggsUpkkTEQM3MMA20YqDeXFwBcsNyA8AaXW6uQsGHjQ4qj9goNAgFbOQUqOEBvW8yPreNy9WtEOOmIgHlsdiE6WEfBVDkQA1hpqN2E1uYBV0H2TiFUkXoxPQV8jXuqKFcqHwTzTRyG4FmZlroZTmIOQVpeiiEUN3WYEvTs17FAkYCZo7IwbdSD7x@EQWMyIsqFMEDXaay2VAcHmwOCQJztH92thW2SeUsdyKgsOtmvoNnVex@B8FPfB/p2DnYNfbC@BYVudylUHycqVCtjVjidC3xlLOVGtrM/DmAG@274ZNkZcDMNzoTcR3MmcqDQ1oHOZROh8fPDFqygBSQjRQVMAM95XRBoWBoQurqP7gyudMOlnMpBkHCUKS4R9EsGMDZh19Nej/DwZv3yJlXc1U6PQHXNmj3UGIHKU9p0onoieVwSwyKvTYz0ijQuyqOXg/MbMNB8yys/bKDtfzQwVqOdI5u3H9/YOahRsOLom0CCSH4AspXtdEWjeHoMiviwMsD8wGSQjzjKOUjXN61IEG8YCgmd1S1bABwCo8YguEexhVDR/AHnfvVo26ioYMQVQO4VwVa6cl4eMz5vRuXxgF2eg4rusF6Ues84qdlraY8W@i92Wkc@bxVx5vtsyZml254HS6QToByK50QOvY19AF3EmRYZidZj9wwfXMu5TIRJUASHKmW8Tkabl2xxqL4JFkr60C3qaa5vie5Tj8YRPS1IymlEQDZ@qoHPh9yZWkJLT7K2kISykvrOzr96NAoeD2XQ8gyoNqJFjz@T1cIrQ8IFGHNd2@y7ZgDhMOowSBLFpZTF3@q5zrYZ0dMSiJnCWEfgvDt/oI@hrrJdUfaSx5pVWNl@pO/4pcGmloCGSKIYoKImGFz/UT3RA16zch/sf7EEnouRlOTbL9AIUzMWh6EKTMedKHYgACYlhfpYWMJ6WvNbaIw9hbl4QCx0yujjizsx7qSPlmKK0NPzSLL3jXsP4h@70CmmBCyMtMMyhbP/Rkwf7j/Ye7rzfDNR8fsGek8sFQByk1wFZSBwwvGFr3WBNE4uF4BLQNjxsXsAFxqCgRPNMY98Dxi1iEJFlYAXVsAnd1DvuwEn66auFOUVf4UPHYCT0EBsfCxpGBEW7a6My4rEJb@zPkX4GQTDyK5IErXww7oigtEofGq6t9yUaDzoG25YUVF32H@Pohr8sBmTGn5osBhviAtFhSscRdXvogvJCp82RNZAUA0/HrmyrPwBdGOfWTS8txhRMSyN1QUMAXVmKy0YZMLUBbsN3VE88I@23FLXE6FqR1ZzER8EWmj@EXeuZoDqloLcCVKSvWEnzdvM2mQKXRkhXgSSIuEEHOXyCfYFNQJCkY6eo50fIodwCR02RV1AcvRjjmC5wKSkv54pKIS@BWgZqGsisAo68CUM9MAZC4AoAT3B7dNxgjgp7vqE7PXEjNESZBbnvFhRVazxrNp0WCOjN2zRvOGPdmLYaSitdJdejbITh01Wg3oXiIe1GDkC71AikSd9kBT/r6tfZWVenratLpGA4CvscYUQe7oAg9dIFft0159seRpDmPaWNhbASBn4lLRkQsjEqhw/ElAQNCnpaID0J8yWA0IviIVAO8K25CGQ2mhELTNNgAPxDI6ldakpfl3DRWQu5xmJWcGhYHE2B5dFAyLQFDTMUedAERwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwlHHrD0EVQTG9DahY4A1DkfhyID7IJxzmbMxoaxSYZWHPDcET4guvDyJuEiCg2AL3/4WS@EE4ttIrmjI8UBFq5IdmFEkTxFFgB9@ZQEdKSha6Iaj8smnjoWKiIiR30F6LqS620x8NYID2ld/vBPLz/@7uXXP778@FuXH//65ad/fPnpv1sTXqGOWd/MNJuCmG20CJ@8lvlbe@qtnTu37pRoDkGehMz/X7/063/3G7@ymPcl6f74o6/9@KNf/ttf@fhvPvvoxx99@Sc/@vpPfvTVn/zokzdK1/k/f9U1/uvHbpjkKQ6NzCcYpgfJDQbQi94Hqa2xcev0jKytrUH0tbUtqIm1rS2SIVvwFOC5Bv3mFvhm4blFGuC7RlrkosWBBuuTJaN9Ih0/F03dGLSBWxpmSkuL0OWdnU/OyWDQmIjQzo95Y4NvXdDZJdoX4IwLy/QuVtohXTmDeX8Hum9mm2V@VdINqdmQm63mWarZzaSbF1JWaYGW3bbw4afUdEMRRQHckLekJPGsdCHFeZvQkBBINAbeLGd0wo4t5EFdmhH8PWsCPRGwSiCk@TF5ylro5A4OrX5gjgZTbz5APF4F8imOPc/Wh@AyGuR/8/zlJYs/Lwot6MiRxMjCgViIw14oaYymjC9yLKdNaWF5UtRjnQi9oRvo0rsiqBviXEeTXEtKggB9CPVhkGixH1q@AaqF7pju2J8fo1s6dIipg@vRYAzse3dgjTjTGLhA6dsAk8SzJIhknPAR2LRRFK1riHBjs0aWgVMM0BvTpTsWVD5tvXQUQ6FJn@i21Y3HsvOF0QsxTq1K4xAZE7L6juuZAiACYnB0nRJdBsfVo9ncfTpSdI1Xhr60C0C@a5lBltyzXZ1i1HWAFuaoEedCZvFBn4UoB2aXsx0i9EC0EFkNeGZX2uDo3KbrDYBdQmlwykaN62gYekiuP@qKwQSicinsoOY9mTYEQtop6aqqWjDyvUrkh7QAyB5A1aAW54BKGHkJCnimw6rdY8MokU776PHdPTbWQDsn7I5w3Kk9dLtjkMNCPePAdPpZsgdUZDnuEFipE8V/eWwfuG7AtGKwrBrJYEqmNRzbOh0juTqMcWM8w@24Nh06uSnqLPzY83VbZ4M2ke/Ouw9BNn56dFgTK3OBJP1keGPaOG63PFmGz/35mTo6SxlNp/iMMPn1PI/dXLTQEplL6FFCjyEupQRZMdSiqTV2DAOeKfIFhl2pbsThFBqOyUizhM4UlbqfBL3egrNGnY8F5CX2zDlHndnyygV1yOvMAuVZIFxruRBmHlCBhomXXK4MV6Th2HIOINaZR4l66HQBpoBD9wu@Zeo7W4GJ0k/IweIJ@4FpRxNwB@bQxUkm6CVtnM0A0R4FWbZG0oS@YoRzCZRN4wwVdAk6RLwqaEETGwksNJdYo82mYzkSThRx6xIJR4irtOGA1s1m9nzGQl3QjOngw2adzQij5uExpUdiY9frbQCxWa9GC9ZWBcOUksk4GIVK8wYxaDHpJPi1osZLGnw6JM3RKFXOl0Donqiy0JwU91rnScmnaOgRvtmc3JLV90EmwdWI67elvlml64FW4Ksa@SQpww77co6GYsO7xgC4C8lMFlEJ9TN2eq7dFdhcEtAaYVoIVlA4oR@vkgwXw5qWFy2QpCtUWVTkqnNrK6/BvVKl9esB5lZjxoBQfCDnx9mTc9I4zpIT0R/ZVgAiEsoTg3BVkXN13Sadz9I9T5/6XLgepEZ2Dt5@tyG3GARuqOP8UInV4iRa/gtam@eOccE2mHBVS2AFtNens/YWlheEHIhApxIg@wCDJVAlcUJhiajkY57PytIzQZ9LmVRcmg6zxExfiD1bDwLTYTTHJulWo5vNpoTJ1GjyW@HQfIXIdP7C6kEuwQ@yWCWHR3f3Dg5EFOhSyT2c56hAcwTREYSRVYWOMDlf@Aq51U2SWxgnjcotB00N1PV2GB@IugpEPzZxNgfZTt/0UuCYxikKA5zprBCNyKSxEEG4NskIKI5iYClQtrcYsMrS/D91jh33NK7xClB8hmIS0J26XUEpMy2OHeuF6EP3QgVNCBLqU9BL1NZTlJOtK@lw8dkQJ1hBqKYCIpSg0SCgM/HrEJgnrVaVzZRDWPADN8Quz9OqoKvEa0pU9TVwBkGGQgij116RZw1ZKLcy68tA0YVY4QJvVv45uAhhEbRvLk12PUXb@7WGzPLAZswY937q0@WPi9scKmSdGXg2MkuDR4uLKNOha5EW1xQtrliCRoashA5YYEEilpAIl9@HNEv9KecHrRejUYdUmpzFSFcR5eT8nOKQrKuE4hBMCmGVcRFpxcCYHrhQmgfh0vt5mYC21nC5BbbZJsdXYm1elEWZRycmp0snV4RR4YT6Rpo5EwYt59il0yGxqS2LSh4FwDj28Ni@HhNXatLHQlA6mbqQLVUszmfLH3Z69LEkDp0OCCeaqQMdaA5lXhAWdemAvuiY8/XoVxZXRM5Mv2eLN2nfCmYivHhNSKFcooF7nY61KiiUHldNRe@lWDhAClbFnKjMinh1/Q1ZQGy4mjR8/7ePuoDg6@gfQBeAI2@xoQ2dMlaFsAyzC1HRQh/La44NEI9tS6cIoKbXgTR0D4qk27FhOWg6CS0I0LEPcUg9rFkgPnyAKLkyGTXMOZsRi97LE1k2qeQAMzRWhb2yHoklRac/QFHrUiQw8cYyaSTKlFglmBM2BTGnKCODen2mokVDhBItq/fBOBizJ0izr61Ea4T3chQshJTzekcxJbZ@@4Yq9/TjcdcVRsf9WAItLAk7Kz0dHxKgow@nQ9toXF58VkC2Hjp6rwo267SkU/p6HVX4ztgfCR2qVXeZjTaE4Q0peDZ7rgpihfvfYsNqrFk2fbwhJYbQgVDC1QASrrgU5pBmXUGzrXemKF0MPj@VxTPrwHFqRiYjayumVkej1fFRk6Txy@XlsSeiwfCxTOeX2KrOUKWiBQ7Xeb6mVqE/soa6LajdOeNKpr1sYv5a0HhOj8bBLQh0H8KNRI4djzG2dW9muoHErw0jXxuQjjpHy3Chgx8RpSgq6ow5RovAZiBx@Sx9zE30W8sQFm2fEGLT8sbuGgEujlxBPW/AutiiRFz6OUcOorsKJ4Z7ivcqb38A6iV7Lu@7Xi7N1RuwIcE2bB165pWMf2FYD4cNX0OSp5Zv0sdyxB4vzWhg2EvdF4k9GrCbH4B7HQH7lu365JA@b0JQ3wMssOdy0p3HpaU7Ah28njffwG2i2fxZhep237ULpb6kw2NlrY@9HnL48P2mvCzmRYryGl4UCTquo4TvlRz8WPKOX1dBdNOehys554w3dKbLGFI4W7G6dCDc406F5SW7J5doTFFig3orEsb1K6f6NHr/HJ3EKtRGncRoSgVkkOMwQrkEhsBjQvPPk1ru5tS6b8aUroEtvq4Qc5V7bJvQLdHntSolqqx8zhiKLL85i@rZY3NsLlUdHnc@NMMO480Tl8Psrodj6Th8j1su4lAvQ2XujXKHPS/abmQaOk7XvV44WWReI5CnR6jmPgHDEzRcj9F3xqOF2lvQq5wDhprBKGqibnchF@jzeflK6TUyzoJk7Zv0vlHXYboZLm2q5WVZDkWPubmPBctNOpAWx/3QYs@FhKnLLOVZWJzv8uaMy9OgaJlfPLeSpairVG8auFyWHMsxgyk@35A7dlzX/jw1BUwSN7y6oGcKdJHoTTV2TXwJtz@Q2eCCj0MSnd6qYQXWe4RaIeAH1d2bKn1@cuaNalPA6cchTg0tWleNrDx1bH3Y6eok1Tl109eB4l5MHJ1hq0TtmwZp6PCEIpbE4qx2um7HtHX2mhRyN8Uri9qSth3OeuIsKZsbnc1kJ67wjtEUymp1QT0YmEOTWm8Qr/UunuoQvlYGmrh4r/KemKYhTfZMY1WAkQXN2sHnwmTsnOwSuA4oNgEuMEMFwcYljKHramQ91D3LfbDz6O35WfUwwP5Q75v3Iu1gbkgAV8gwxWlmXD44UCF3sCkZEC0EGwqWzrE59aP30ogPpwZU1Hi4stEZOCz4Bq1s1aLH612YM3AHzsAcsJXGsW0VlQIhBRRwSD1Of4CLnEajhcXP83iwXduexwOyGMZwXLe3NI093ASJe3eWxmc7q8PXa4ep9IA1PjSsJNOBOQY@7ruBOzIFalsV1MYhDfZcxXOiOdqfd6zkRo0WUBG9f174r9Wt@robjEb01R7ZY58@aFSB7lF9nTzRY4sq6PI31@uLL91hRwwdxXDFBZ3GXd6mO1ZgDHCTMKNIs@92jIH1ukyHBxNI0eAGs76R7oaYsYhwF51BoQf0elMR6aU273@Ir/1VlR6Ok7DOIDbc0L8vG4ui23CFkX5s@GzcD02kgkOfc62Lbdat0O3OlRdjK5gBnVuFEw9ksoF2NKzKe7h4YKUkQlfDz9hhuKhgJZVS4RUFVcGUQUBQViW7uC5rrolpGnss5Q2Gaxz3Iva8EpPhghQ6xGXNDT6C@wLpLKykWSpZO4Nx37/O29iYcxekFXys1sjpgtS5cVfoFnQnfK3CoGpLuFMN3m0QP8bmjRMD@RtnBmg4xRZ014JXG15QK@OVw0O2NfLZkwg9dVWwcIENqJlXZ7UYbqbL9cSwYrpmj43jo@l1Mhno1yC89qE/Fwyc6MVhYOTTrNNmPMlx@8CvBZvMAkdhV@lKSxfALK/@uHsT3n9k9nVcDfvACnDd4BKqoO1j2cKZ18L@0lj3rS@NoWSriA0337M5M29@2STalsB7qPct4/5CRcSZDBEcLjpkrwXyR6frdXE6sHxccBMbbhhzQZJjRIxU1wYReknIq4PP8bkDswbE9rItDb1sgNgdTXHLz5SabhobtgI6gBi@V2lRq5Y33ZiJ0/FwNPbD1/I80CU98wOsQ8bO/FMLgAsvgGuSgW4Hywdh50YTQZAK@7uZcXmSFfKBZbt98kFJJiB3BcRCOXcJ4dyBnvcJrhfxnCWUSNN@w7k71PkFJrf5L6BuTVyZ7ljBzQMYQYBrR6I3FoZ1Cu4pyAMP8Cluf14IwtFyjDyY6@TifaSv6aKBwg7dsWeYaIwPh5iXyEPo5m609NXC7fR4uMXpvGZjuDY0IzDYS5uG4TrjQPDGzo3cv3Aj96/gAUFz1U1SX9p7@DQ9X@t0gfDrBMnoCKmZaeXs9hVishyQpVbzy8XQkdh/lx1tc0DXqb4mzg6ev2NQtnzXXaaCPJlCR7GMmY@Hd00D57Jem8Yj96HruNC7jIDxDQ9MthF7YZXB8ogY7QFuNQY8dF@bzCEFu6JTYdKDPjI7UI/2zPQmfQsDfFcP9BVdCx32oipZbHotTVh2x/Q@pONZc@ZVWuNihu6bE6oGrCYM1taEwDCY9IpDTQttYWFywR@5rsOelHvK8FIe3swlgLXTx5vP3oq42ntB9V6qSi0W9fEJW7pgdtlJAavK6pkd12bPGxbEOBabqNY9y/SlB7jxnLoVckQAacq/kVcUb@QVMy0GJNMT3aczx8u1ghlIZfI51qUMdM9wcdImNNywZGRut/hr2HG8gJzNZncA8RPgTLoxDs92fF227GFnSB8rFYC52jwwIZkurlQ7nDqBPrlemWzwJdxfPrfMKN6VHbElbNQFknoC2kV6uQJ3BXvWiD4o5105g0tXigiOZRovdRxocileZsOrC/5QNukRNa4Ybp1rLnQgVNLpNuOlLWZx3RQIIrYpBAMP1HApuGmENjrjYsmQ/nho4rzn4kTCSpHT9Qe0sO7yKd6YiXqmEB63BjwjPnqNyXXCzkqJEcHD//GddyToVNuFXHTuA7Co108qQ@bHnhO@3oTSnrh@0LMmjyHfuLh8FdvAYuUhCrxYC0DTxqpCQO05Y5sNCPTnFv0Mu1SNEujhuYJgU7YcmILpnAj0FK7J9RK5bN@QtIOHqgZmVwg3oeNgufAg2kIUBwvfS@b05nkgrihUJIbYSSEXrjFchtzTiAOA/OQGwsinb2nkP9l/8PhIHPnK0n5oZ4CL7q/JZQu72tWSPDdK9KHuzU3NsbVQXcsPpDuHirD7YF/EACvwzUbvBXjh5NLCa@VQZHSQpqSv1F7Q1wyWC3z3jx4@yMx23JHU7sBzh2Z63nv38DCLGxjeOVzqPR/7HrSOnjtZGX1/T1HSS8g33Ja5iksuSWkVpCMTtEggxvvsUIzXClGGOzK7R9OR@S50ksip/TdMvrCykI/0E6uPrZCUVyKKNlRSFgu59Ny6X1CSTS9@r6rPY2uE3NKgL4m9Vq6QQAlBkzxtuZRw0@T0VWmFyOHk@OeLpMjXqXX@KFdJ9/@pGVMUZRWeD/Ue1CvJr6ysxQDLpjht9@QNZkPNUBkRYichAKoSrNcuVi4KQ2DdEj5wxDx0BGNn5cqMmwDEzoWlDf7UdKa6I6C0FLqM3FjK@MCcm6uJF4uc4DnPS6et4vXWJGVQY4TmI2/Oa3f3zn7kccDcQ9vbj56SJ7oPGs8SiOYcxJlk8aGA4zV4fNeqgYv9rgecmvUT/dFyuq@QQ93rus50MtdUcBYXuzp6YmUcB200kGlbE2sZ7zbY@MyT5StBojTYCnl3uiDnzZ@IEUa4/MqvK4os0/NO8K3IzHqFgEkKTfoUD8ua9zraj0nfwH5ZBIf0Uq3qgTnBFQNslHKZcrqUfxdu4O3F9Gp2eZNf6Qa/3A3pXfNDR9xModwAMH@DH8mLsfcD1z4duOKu7pk3oOOmrJdvyHp5jt@ERzDT2avQvFpoxZXg4WspvR2ZgZcbDdyOlVsQkRd3Tq4cbg90j64/6Lvh4nlmX57U6ThqyA/1l@Z8Ez6e8QFzMMYl40sm0jogiJlO32InrpE7brBHbTdoC/HG0OVzzdbo7nh0hZXg4fRXuNN7oJS5pz65g1t9ZvLhEuUS1xYtd18lTJF4hAkPF7x/tBMl@vhQUudSnOXi/ScLzrgZLnh8OOfmmZPJKm1LmKxSXpb6zFJ9dJRbSHaz/uzkNfsqoGcDVhe/V3a5jO@8c3i9daKmMAiGduTzju6YEZyuG9DdUfE43GQ0Gxx9b0AJIOJjSxZ0QS9iWQDDl9ptPK2k3V5FJUfm@3RgGfpKEpgTFOuZgB8eCmROcoMg/F4HjbKyAbjHMdc@HA0sZxJahjN3XOtGUh/6UYl3yKHtnpJI4ZlrPmGPBVH0E9O5eVOTUNZu7pC1@V53AU/s1P/wtQpFd1b03ndMz1sW5sCQ7kWWd9X0khDvHEYBlvnu2i4Oknat8XCZN42aySzz8hYa9tVI1jIPPLT@eOB6zjLPqGIqlTvmStBrN/gNp6CtLfPo9HrLnPd8d5nzw7EdWCikRZ6P3DG0nois9rxIeqtv1ptNsSLOrHgGrz/w0vMuwCmG7tgH8c6y01eDCh9awYLjFXxTNzwE2HREx70K9x2XfNGa5XO@EC9XYumdezOfxXHiMc4U0t1xM@OqnVKjqfZa8n1p9allOeE51vCK7@x8pX3PdZgtPT/vE52utATafd220qsnQtXXzIQim2P@5ERb1sqA4d@bx@i700ksOT@x6V7d0LarQgH6hpEOvxHh09WXijY3KMCWjKxY9jZj2V/aG@rG/JDjwiEL0bSRP2Pic5qFd/jozs7Re08ehPYv6sNOlEJ0Lrp6l63aitdoXBlGoSfHS4f4FPyBDn0XHUERcNv0lRm093YePInY8QBEckAlHu42N9AU812S6nq@PizHEuTDaJ/SXWh7aJ5xovtT0xXGcaFYf7dMzV@5e@Dq4VA3h5470ulabTwyg8Ox10uv3MiqLld2Dh@sYqvvRMU8fPvhO1@6N9vm9MgaEllU4X@lZYiKKF91Uq87adedcted8tedCqJ8ReZbIQ2KpZs2L2ti@Tps5Vre1esZVa9nVL2eUTXO6JyTfN1pSYpLsKXIS9yuhVOibLD95iBczJ/o72fDk6XY@QxsV7wvRp9dSKUc4Onpxa9fzW/xx3OvU@t47us63c4PYc/PyVq4hR48@GhTfnhoAB4PaTljE3f9s@/fBLV1SKZWU/JlsoWflqoQRaZp4vf4yuwUviixBlk/CzfEVyrKBVmrEb7Ck/BIgvhQbXYwNADGI22hUEQ4Vsh6AD7r0XZ6Qr90Qs4JHa4VDDw5FGyiNH@wSDU8cADytH72ZP/J3uHRztHTw4bcuggPJIhK4TiQWnTsyS2ty0PhQ7yBmsyOiacHYdiQHP28BQ7z@lG5CH7ZabFotYWizQrFb2Gc9TPHkSR6JoMkXED@BJ6lRn1RTgUnBjsqMa2g8DiOCjsegZ7yAHXEQPM0Tai0CpGXJTzSfR@KFfpf/Tga9cWP61Xw83qYcHiyN4jFfdfthin6Jnn9FaV4b2f/wdODPRJlcEY1p1Y3GNTKeXbwe3jmG48nNNj08JJkGCUJdVWrJe8lATFJMUkq9BQNeug6ng@XjOkBz98IY2@Q1DqFDxhMxpUi/bePpIukiHs70hA2GWUqCckCzVNCwRPyjoBIyN2D/Xf3Dgjmf@8udUYUIQhyhBv9//IHXfbZkuhgrejDgt4wVAOhtnzX6lbwXA3DJImcooaH83QJHirHjp4g5oR@AoRSHh2DmvvUYJoedsTNHwYSnZAxO8QDa45ygPmY7PMi9HCM@Lsm8eeZOI4e3gf0fkrPnrxyLGOaHn3GPqPIDkyNQVPSiz6RgHO0oLZS0cXyLTyaA@uh5469K40Ed83TU0hFsoPfXMQvO@r0CzyQ2bETsFPcwpOdEkChYsyrsmSdZpZ9r4efC5jcXING0jH7lkN8xwJJNaiQD4GCcX60wo5uEYR68lqUCHSFmgTUTecCMj16iOfgE2G0h8fxNT3p8td@RepXCZgDMH8SmifyHbB9LbT1wPx1Zn4mIYFKyWufaYnzMp8hPKY1LAHLCNezfvYz/Awrn1pXlOO2d5JJ5uUqPJRqnuTJrfWmIKw35Nr2ug6IDF5MmtCcpY3ciXl30Ovu96Umz4M4m5OkjbOzs@S9jSfWszwpCF1LLbyYTC@0gvZicqEppRfHI6XQEF9MWnyplj1uNRst8uTJ@6/ar9L85ISOYqaAwHYf80qOT1TK5GyroCWOy/iJNijhMXkJ13GP4J@aX3bnzDqaOz2g2yRPEs0mfjOVL/LA9pIt@FNO8RwuxjMadbEubrVevUo3dD2YTIllWSO/24XbHZCUqqYPCTS129CIWASJNOmbIhGu/HDSI5Mds98f7@lTa3wv2BaLYklU5xjT5sMP3guv6ntPnxLylDx9@vJgBRtrZTIpQWhQ8yRyfAASZnZCKm09n8CPrP3lZ2sX2bMn7c2//HgomWv4eoyvTy4eovlQyd9aW7t1504ul1VVlZmffPDkF3d2dnJ3s/knjfxWTpDXNv/iz9fWVHVTldZavq@0ko3j4/d5Vc7x4l9@P9l@8uRLvl/X/utHr@oKPorwOCFFUsZLIwoY8VmCWyH5PHnTK/EyocCVmNJfOxG5n60Rpb5V/O/ffPwiESTqqvSeB@8g8SJRKCWYEQxg0yLbSaKe2MRghYvEVKrVamAs/vd/D/Hr7wAc9JluwqOej2AVpom6UKNRzhP1AhgUVYV0/@@PPprLIfAzYCU1aJFCKXLbBobYaPC5ospvteDaoNcmhycaCbIkReGcYBCYLlFKt5XbaLHAAi8HXjgM1UzgZyYfbxPx2UEG@oSM@G59Tbq7KcAljiRFUZuKchvYr3Bro1YToF@hzVbT8rfxtMk07Q37buAS8/Z7C1fivf8h11Iw1ff@ea4DsmsZpudmuURhbfv53XodSq7VtY16hl5hc6Mtr1jiXXcbuM7RYOxZLn65svoAv8FS5@WSymez2e2DNkQhkwkiU5hMxDaCIOy72Al2iW3CXLBhh46MKuGqI09okdidxYqss3DkebIBraX1fHW4xB5ef/Uf/@rbf/VN@vs2vf8zHgzldK2etAGBTqDh1OHarlSMep2ve/xZE@11oDa5UqqUpPZFM7XRqLcOQMB9@zyZ15Lk0J5m2ypezXSzQePXabL1MHm01xMz5zpzqc@7hR4sMHWAd4gpkojKOVeuGGuEXAnHJaI1TULjpN4ScFi0JjSUQr4lsFiNbagcXi2W@XYrIaxPMe@tuppXH5PtOrvIYN0nLuZGUwtRQcL81mdlm/nMbPV5p0Q9ilafhfm84cI8laFkvhTKnvUoo9trlbVSpVBRpXZ99VWdxcCLBjVN84mfOEnEV5WEdBjhMxFT5pzbs/maiKuFRARMFuK@JhyXaNQaLbMFbST8L7todWkFha@GJrXNkyrQh6oJar/Nywq0tu12xM634FqDH/3DFVvxuUZdQmca5Pq1RirKhqpJ@VuFPRX74KsX8YRGPUN5pNCqZ0TklYJ4JRAHvQoxOp3OS6MDMoqud3RDVwJ9rE/0qR50xp1JJzDGBn6QmDxBQa8d4sDT3LxbciOUiEJCyyvridtI4Zpaxm/7gpZSKmllVSsqWrGgFWW1lNdKZa2Y04pFAKgVVa1czqmqVihqhZJWKGiFMn4/GcIUIIyGEIp5raxxiVeNNXLA@NuEZKKrmXnt9VSkHA0vanDxFgR3kgARamwcZ7nEP8NVV1SFbEA3KcMDZENqJCr9QQl3dWvsZzmSALHvrPVqo/Fqg8zXlhDmGV5ie7uVES4uGmCuVsP/Zj02VunFTFDU1kUms/msDtLQs3ojAyCfhSBFgVCgYrtOWpvUK04tTC7032y1@uCbGfl9JBmBZuIFZCKz2disubv0FmnrFFqQyuZCzre3KaltQ6z6OnQL6UxmXRDWGgC6EXZQEBgJMiwiQIJgKRBlzs5@zptsbgKTudi8qF80Ni8uNjfhv0mfF@EbXC/Q5yKZc5MFd5tZwj99za6LiwXfKMzMv4V8qtmQ6k2pGfKqFthFqY4uotQEQx3eEK6hqaUW9o4oB4mtf5l/MTt7xi6Y5ZYIueYSG2QjgUcqaYkNLvH88tP/Fe/m5ac/RJmWwM@scIkzQriEtFEm1I2@yiDYPXTIQ3Y5YMY7sqILOtQfoqPDHg5qypL0XCQVgarLKaVUSIvY/bfdXhv3rIrkOQSFYHt9ExpRxHsJr5YKfDujTFWS2OQLRcpuf@HalUwm/9VztVxMMm0cN10@933/4VwuZ/mEwFVVVgTlvM7OxmWHl//Csutf/cKqi0uclwniKEUYXrgEkFFCkkCL5BL1zSGuAMQPfwj4BbeT2vvC0x1h1x2O9ICq6ziWB6JCbX@vVi7XUY0y15/QxrNxdwOeCvz31qAQpNmDoM1ezRiCiN7saXm1iVrr2zpo78DohM4L/D14iT9yZODv4AX@yNFL/B0E@CMPO/g7eoG/nQ7@job4u/MCfw9f4u9pH3/NL2iaUuXX9ZPupAv/ycv1yfoZxVVGKSsX6xOe4SyxVW9@AdDpJ6tkO/mFBh0VypdbDfRtgccXAm9a0Wvl6qimVoc1Iafmqi9rqqBWw@9cuH7Wn/pZXLhpGlgTppHi1S2VT1cZpWi5cvoLbJym0q7ZdNCFpPCzISnXT2fAkIJOLB0FfyWEoETLjz45mGJ7fStqGodItHLe9QSdWD48wCGjlRXXS/70Gx9/nKzVkkKSHg@fAzcBvzkND3BolLOKmi1mc1mllFWyUA45qxSzipwtgV4pqVk1m88WssPsy6yWVeDfajTazxoq2F7CT4U7l33ZagB/zd8utlqNl61bSrmVyamQGchSLv0FQAMRTfb9qeoI8MUlamRdWVdkWzZkpaN0wGAR2SPyQB4oXYUqm7JJ5Kk8JfLQVbpgMuEng8mSe0TuE9mRHQgGvmAK2nKAph68@vDrASAPfhYufOooskEgIRsVUvrlJ6WNMWVy3iZvD1w/yI6aXIMkCf/cfP78OQ6ziwWrhR8CaPDPnzeljZZaLhER257YbjxvJlt8k8djYtVyjnSm5lrzOQ8SlMyzNoouJOH7jWSrmpCaTYnVIKCe0tbFRbu99@huuy1hV94kZj2znYF@aHu7Bv1S@NpK1KtbzQrt6aLeLiFtbjXrmoDmQgY6LRXcyH0TSCcrZT7nNQMM7/oaRUDr@elzUNhSp6i2nZ7A6zQyvNeER5spdNRbOn2vOWelBrgwrCS9twTCggFy7XjTWDiDP@i//1x/61/W/@FTkk41WunU2cVmil5p/KXTZxdnF@Gznk6lQktqE37oAHaMcnZRRyMNdAamRirdSl9cMDd4ptKbDGA9TVKbdRp3Fg66vUScJE2WPVL/Y94kLkwqvJrJ6nN@c9MzzptVykRzcpkk@OegPOmzqZFmcyIDc@hEx1cLDlnXz@k4crpq4Lfh1jsNpfUX36dHlG@laaB8rlpVNgizqDm1Ws1FtmKpWi1FlvVUqnz9qstbSgFUvFwOWGwVLFsRWBmsELdBXmVIjTTh2bp9myVSUs/PI5harpCRcUqqWo1SykOypq8btJ2D5ne2/5ge7w2MIp8gyA/CQfWUTD8PcKLbqeR6u1aZ3L6dCj8Bu7WTvn1bLcvn54pcyjTkrAxMtqRmhXK@1eB5EXrfgdv16YTDrXwrSdKul3qEH@sEkClBIbfUOoVeBv6r5oro3cgDFIVCEkC7aaUbwDNYV8PzrKtBartVAr6tlaFEsZqY5JNVPnEG4lSpaPXI2nqb8TC@ij7kX9CVIMBYgJMsXuTsIkGJjOTy6RRw5jSI4BcJ/HnIxFlPnM@nqzlZTpxd8CywUi6z0GmSK6RKmXL4q62lSR3kS/ZDIVnL5DaKG9s4Wuj7k@UX8vnqmVlTLmpnZgW/W3NRNcLvN@LOaPP2ba0M9V2SE@TuGM9nyDa5sJOogayBoio8mlwymSG3bnO4bdxLVqrblOiUUp4kklXmKCShsyGlckaR1I28UsLa4qwenncA8hanUFStkTVOpW98cGWGwDV0THCJmCW/7s914SJd0iF9vEgf1XpiEZtexCbMnz4NIw7ksiv0ja00Lh0IiFzM@GLTGlpeYw0rSR6MDQsHFJ882NndO8qqmwJJqPd2drPq4dM7CQWt@ZmdemtoP9jbufv4KUR48mBv53Dv7f13954@AXefnM6uuE@Lera4h5szLbGfkve4D72Xumnq5tg026fj8ekL8qFltS2ocnsMZXP7HvHNNhRppM@KV4XbsHz9ww91b0Qvcvm9r1x@75cuf/8bl7//lcvf//ZPP/32V@D@AdzfYO9v/HE5j8@ffvrrf3j5e78Pjv8Z7j@D@7OffvrbH7Gb2n8E93@Zc/tReM@FYzcHsL7200@/@f2ffvr178D9u@H9nev3r322/P72l1ffGO@bf3hzmG/8e7j/iMGKwn7j95gbvq@F/z0W7uvfufzN/8D@fxH@0Pj7l7/5I3yEll/9zl/8l8uP/5Oqlv7i315@@ZuXX/748sufXH75X6uXv/1vFXn@8YeX3/6Tv/nTP/qbP/039P8D@vyjN/lffudX//p/@@v//a//NLw/g/s/gOmzv/5P0Iz//k@@h/9v/snf/9n38P@//MHf/8m3/v5r/zM1/A4z/OPv/jF7/vjjr/z4y7/x448/XfH8yo3PT9/A/dN/Bpc3z@ebwHmTcn1el09/rvz8U7AxSwVoACj3ly9/@6tAvL8JndblV36A2zTgXvH/garQMD9gtv8PGNTrZUYfGUxwf@vyK98g7yOW/ifAEvzJ@@9D7/R@2M2///77IQY/QT9wf586smsxIvOMfGc@n5BZOKiG7xLSeP68hVPGC6Cp5aef/sb3qS1hVup0OhB7/ZJaymyA2rZRLsfzhJsY/qsxyC/MfolFSPmS5jhONczBJ8jFFhL7BPnf5fc@uvz@v7783u9cfu9r2P8LuXJ2JysorxGCIGD@DcJhwMKbhMOAkHw7Q8dLhQyYzXMJ9xFtnxNShXJoJa05C25Kvd5GBX4EHpXKxllW2GqSAivxBY2LG5FAtlUE9VZma00iip7VNjQdAko5Fo5UnG05lylu6LrEtc8l3LREzsmcUVJYSEkNccm8cKWWFEKWFDX2Wo8AxMXgEhnMboZKRBuRnJbXyCQTlmQSTs2jOwSabFDjhLAJlQn1nnATOoMf/WfGCUcyVEhiUmhmZqSGMF40@1@EOyxIHtLKzOZsqPRImOC2wVzowgaaeA40KToXmpnU6mjAuQbwugN6S62WwYg1limwsvzVS4TmJ5OpQeExNouTbZcQxOQOhQIxaxQPtQmLmEF49QgnGQ6daG4ypdpdSLA2uYsOGQROwT5/XquXapM6gnvFkJKZZO7QPCGwWmZSfwX2GoUJ8bjE3VeQlVItk6mXMEEsJKujbJvVVJ4WjpYdZ9VZRcAbl7ZtbRNyi1dKPJuxWkOEsdD4zMxCY0CMcvCcV1T@OZ9TZR4CNzMbYdnoPzLSe4Nif42mGybJyo4pr1FgpP1843kYkIaE1ARBFEUCNy4j2SLbZItjWMtkaGbglQmRSImFEkfsQCimuAytdYY2gA/O9POdRFVzVdBPqgSdPIPDr33RtUkytz7BdWdnJJSZ5fATlhecDmFyssadnevhurR1nVyAU4HDEDTN2sbnvjCziLX19XUuUec1/jGdf89IEvGOK3R1IbQ9qmlVCF8o8@hs0qWWDIsPcXdClqPmKhaTXH70/UROLia49ST9XDBhCZFbGXZvb2@QW4BW@p5zm9BFfEJGc3NugqFxM5PhVUi07oJtg6IwQ6Fxz0iihn9wT1Byg974ie5ZfpbLUsaXhZdYS6A3efz4cZhf6vCsxmWgHaqagnacex2PxxDd7OI6h2xWFLNiNhu@RfqmDmJoEKlv@BbXEfVkXiNUiiX8TqhjDBAv3KtXr4A2OMRFZd8JQiOpqbkS9SSUDCa4vE4fZjl2ioJtT6NVvGquzLGhFqIUcoSkKEXAlSa4XDUFNJ7m2Jo3Rl7RlUqqpVKShoQaE1MQjIEpKMip2Lpgul@K5IsLVsjZvBXHTtk0Ai7AiBfksvylSvl05Ln7mOw@fvhw79HRqFVrQW9DP0xrtkeea5i@n0LPnUd3Gf2q5UIaZ7ux9EcVFXknt1eRkZAz@3cP9g8rhOEsrLwULUmVrl4IMVNWuMRo9N5mwsPJDM/k8bNMLn@Iz8oMGSm1rEHURJ1LGCYqaECp@Ie7Sg7MPhLwQ79/x52QlJzl@axSQLU6jcsLIDu/6I4JHrvIznoA/oCrJ0UoMea8fibMTeehQ50cqBwzCAo1EK1cigxFZlCKBQzwmH2xTOPqh3tHAPnoMVFUWSQHbseCTNXfJxOREOACB@7QdLPCBY2NPOnIGroYwsbJh34wWMevwPJNmZ9D0DodgJKzqqbhEFKukFXyxdbamn0mIJwmJZozXBt6AdYzAXHyFlyEe4sjb4ETXMIF4dyR6ZBwZmT/cZWRL@4iJinI/WHg8UoeOEOawwmgEB43mr@qiHVoaotTqVxi7YMPAlKv7z26K@zfw9GLyYBEK0sFqysOREo63bFnUt8@IV3rXQt3OIhdyx/Z@hTaMSBsow4YCXCeO3FxcdEDmPv3iFpXqZXF7eLzwqAuHTBfTHSOAI/ucYnb0YANV7xdqdReKbki5K1SeaWpKgcO3IbEJazeGpAbXRu0IbEf79RyipxRwlkeh6R5nq/6kClNK0kbXELheXhpmsbRNkS4iskRunbslVyrCSGbzyl06RiHh9Hrk5oaX2HYya1ZWE1mYdEHPEg/8Igc@RWZX2iLegYoCi6mpt8jjcYw5du3NRy20nJyXHZCUUMuoE7XtZxGK@me6QRIZwR9W4lcMZychHK2EpxtBqRbA3OiiQWn6bLF6fhNeJ@MIWQhB0zxtKIqdJ14JafmEjzB0MgqtZLMJRoJ4AFcowW84P/1X6vBtSb/cv@Alkajxk2Al87foTOGoe/w4riH7uPZ//Hj4bz1xv/wsfvwsTt04Q@95UNk8tXZv1pdsN78D3krstdqFbIamBOgN/jl5DxY//HbH/3Db/7Hf/itT0S8Qlvs8I/f/hZz/91fx@e3vv0P3/qlf/jWb1GXX/uH3/03odc//u4fkLvABKYvdaTNy69/fPnpH1/@8LPLj797@cM/Rev8/9N/F3p9/K2ZI5jR5cr/W@Rvf@3/@LvvfvI3n330d9/67O9@509@/NHX1ZLy449@5e9@57O/@bOvEbD/5Edf/fFHX/vbX/n4xx/9MoSb///kR59EXl@OHcEMLtf/4A5wuf//uvFCBo2rPegChs3wdM463YvQUMq51h7wuAZpbUYHd9Yh9CbbmEjw5JUajwQoBRZz4@u@afdEXOFf4zdHdU1W@c3w9O86edd0sA8J49e7ta5r0G93V7uihd9Qxy14LF4ux1ddB8/oq0Uz@iBppM/6tVO6tb5q1voingbjOboN0Ttudyr6wRSERMO1Xa@WBJU3CXL2u5ZrUyoG807XdVCGdWomqFk42bClabkKlE8cuaMtNV8UiNBQZBA88VZK2S70g94W9L8VNbtmbhWLla5o2KbubeUrefQ24rUdW3m50hfff/jgfhCMDkBiMv1gK1eGCHiiGp59tFWq5PPAUng@06AptvCjxEzAENbWoD829a4Ab1z64QtqqVWh6ddqyeSWpqiCUtHkEhcWdoYwp@oIOaWwJVeCeTSSPdtyXC/Lc/jt1LgWsAIHSj0n5zYleBOoe1yHAuJUneyYfRP7I1pzyqY0QpoAIwTVwdgBY35T6oDRAmN5U7LAOK5rirwpjcFo1HMKuBqMSrA2iNWtQZpYsgxmO4vkkh0oZ6F8UXFcx7zgKlk9a53Rmqv0er2LjbPMzEIS23TtuXpl7fkZ6G1nAgsHtX0h6NnOWWytCjMIXIWMs4I18wQXvQfEcxYuyKnwar7EVxvVmb1Y4KutC257aHYtHb@I3ZTPrscqgEjIoCYgoSbhLiqe6waVjtlzPXMWUFMKUUCWoesBcvxFnFxTxhTPridXmAs0OZvhNcZnx3aN4zAl@qHIZWnl8vwFZ4To8MzuBUsoW8lGjiwqJRusRqzQxLNnXGLj4F2tXge6PcsV1Vw@l1e1QiFfVEH8LecK@RKQjVyQ86oKzCNXLpWLF9BqJelVgn5pjuyeRa25Qr81kNIr7ATORoukXz2y7LOSJjD2k0pXQVxKvOIStw7eVev11eNwKVAl3lWFek3Ll8GkoUnVqFClqoKqCZoiKBr@X2NQ8f/m4VX4q/iEWJrKHeH5RI9AigcFxiEP8IiVwCVHrkt3md0xjRUhdgc6PQtp13N9/58Q5o7uHDOvuxY7DDf2uq/jF9n8oRUMVoR4Ohpajo9b1f65IOwNO5BB5PYswB14eLbrLgtQJE@fwONg/@37R/F7eakfxsfLA3LY@fIQ42hvZ/c@VyB3Hj@6e@WVD8HlyYO9e0extch8o6j5GMQv7j14cNUavnKPnx70xq6HN3fv8dPc7BE74eY8LgfXYqDYmQIJH2hFEQ9VFbJG8sXIoHC4L/B2rkxuh8Z8YWaU0fge23lo@fHWQbZ5tcIdRdsRdYJdQMck@AUrs0uHaOlpi@HIhlIsc9yIOO4pKcqk69q2jp@I762B40D3Scc0UU23baRETPrU9ezuqdU110A0hjTKCn6OGzPB3Qcgw7ExwARAS8Izerv48XZcjNGxxyYZj8hKR3ihExo9qz8ASePUjQJwHV0ncH/eC@Kb81dws0PA0qBu13zs68G5BLfzGAdgEiWe3@X5@3qgS8VnBOWnQYUP8nwfZ7htP@g2qqDdrW3lSsDld2UcdreIOtUlRaoCDpXCed3dVjbaZr@WLyhb2BXX5Mx24r5ZKlXvwcXzvu5kgUdmKziOsuvVHOsZMaqOWgHtvrhBSNM8tzO5miKTSoUNZu7qvhsQSlyVv/3uD37y59@6/Opnlz/8LZT/yF3XM3Rcw46KOKFqdaiPi3QcSC2X8qWyppaypXIpl1cK@TwujFSKpWJZziqyUlIKpXxZyZZyZRDccrhsMl8uhtq8JG2QHRsH8LJMY5c2KgDeMfAD1Zt0SEkc1LkEW@NDXqb0NEnosX1MeBPi8GTH6Zs2wMCxwIBuhd2watBtEyimViQAWScGSdy7tysjju6gBVc07so830VLviTLxTs8b1Kf3RLKprzL4pTw1EU@YBZZvgM1OGYA8EMDPD9Ay14BJ2h43kLL7g6rix5aVIwPwY6ZD7PYkaUIwRy0aBoD8CKGBsF2WDo5mtE9tGCS6HOP@eyCH8@/HWUHfQ5YMAbgflTSnR2e32eWnR302aXFzrOMfhEtO/TieQ8s0Lx4vg@GvgcNm@c7YMRGxvMGmIypDm74UXA8o94JdJ6fMvQggnh@QkPrxjHPtyN3TObdMDd5xG6FWhRW6m1qKeOP59Uo0xhMiy0az@diSw7Kdv/@u/og6Jp9dk099jagpPfva7o1Ge/d67z9dqff73jTnb23D9Brd/c@CDTTsdfpd8KInTZcLsTava/qx8Pp1QtKvd9uV3R7qdcX2@2c7lzxak/bJuYQYr2AnIVXHxMatnfBa/d@e1tftuiJAmwjfxnCu4PXnSG87@gd5hVd1Iu@J50OX4VmAGpMM8Wh5oXrlrB5HgO/drJD3fDcKtonNSLTpfTTRkFuVakHGYLqJFcv0L@XwqeO4@3ps2ljUpNbtUmtqLJRtl6Kb07UvMVn14ZbSjlfWdO3FDWXmVRwUZ3bS5KkoGyRlHJ74yVJPUpvqaBArfHNrS2BbyitrULx2cYYKh4fW6pSquRklaSZVStWII6clAnBR7pRbG0V85VZ5GIxo0tqpVgE0Q/wE4AA0cEB7jZJpU5N/TidxqzTAVIoDy04mdJCW9VeapKd1FgmyTRdndSUKjvYmchXoKVSXfxawNjAU2UIA9oHgBPQoHBJYopXyiUe8iBJuG4Th@0Ycs5ycuni7Mw/O2texKxSAtNsiPq9Lx0dHx29D9wKJJIpG9mrh4O7TzwTeV60Cv7t@7vi/uPIhh8CEO@hcOx64i7yuAUfJiVHTkegRIn3oVsHBTpygziB59riHl02DxJ25BGdxiOGh/WKR/cX4BwO3FOWMkTyqyjE6Xh@An4nweoSvVYHk94lKZoroqdPqUDRrtdr7drQHI6CKRQxivVFQj8iMAOz77O80@@24FftafSznucOQ492Tb6odmqTxEQQyA7Id2MvCxDbNSIoz4du97maMapd/FDCndodBFNtw7tTNWum57keDxosX@1tObWx4@s984np4aEQ@4/XQdDBM1VSPWKm10lzD0Pvol51IdQ94szy@Gg8TOlCvZNedMIJkdgB0ZT6UlT8M5wQgJzz/EW1VyOpZxD0Bdi9dZLqinfSW7kqYOwOaafBSX7ee94jKinkqlQNSiEsaIIUU4gBPV2rfxHkMwb6GLptyE1Y5ccAFRMDwFAb1EdPj6yLqlGzSUogkzTFUa7arzUw@jk@NgWQMQShcd7C@Yz3UDd4MYbOsw7NvTpN6DV/3KGfziFyR1HlQnUCbkoxVx1AfevPJlWvNhp7ZtUGazgDQmiJ9SrgFlAIYF6epy6/@lF6U8jXmFuVgjrHYeu22K5Nqg4eegqUUtNq4JFp5ORsvpSFRzELIoRayCqFrJbNZYViiS7CLdH9FKiGtdbWUnaKJ4TPyhNZVLKKqWRT8nOr@zydPU6hYEORl84G7p4zHhJ0gSpDaqV2eOvpjLoBKOq6RN8UKPECk6liuQD3AzKysgMK6cDUbRYhLRBtI2WvpzDQ@tF4tNdoVSp7k9GXwCslvNgqZIpy5mU6XU2tpWu@@YLOFt2xgEB0QC5yJlr80RrQdDhLRPzxsAG1DialqFYajQ6WtShnNVmDYlrt8/4mX@dbWXmtoECdXdDJAIUwzjI/LwKSEzdzG7VRT7BNqEOlrFY5uo0kQe54YzpRo5VUoSzlN/IymxxhILhRyCIRtyTVjHbcJFPJZFFNJmdKdTpZxYnoNX42L0hV7TPKIZPAsknytpovbPEgAPIVvqzyEGzGcTGXRI5yvkF2ddPXPZxA4nCoguRAVT/jLs4uNuvcROT2hpZt6VniWAZ@g84yjkXunut1s6Rj9UlPD7Ati9wOlHa/InKHoOeZ1NTYw@8QEBafHoeC0VohwAqdXQsG04EJypDITelkYyBed4VaIviOkloMQb7AHeJpGpvqM/wVnz3ceYy/e9sJ3J1Ctr8AfmVwLz17@PTx08f36IkJs43Mn@fa5ohEt6BMxHY1UaVj/rgyA5LBolU@x8LvbZx/J9IaHgVAMqIg1ulxE9sslWZ48JG0Rsjn3SOT2aw/Y@8mbgUF0Bw9BL1BWnSVuGmhmk7e1UGg3CJJqHLdGzZUVWs11CKIJdB1NWQWVFWVKuSinaD7mutA35MzyPRmpo6HSnyRTKd6RoiKfpvU@5l1WZ0mTtp8oazRcw/adUU@JmvJ2xv4dW@BJE6O1@rqRib5pKJlkneTWi5xkmqu1zPKNCmRjYw67eEaNVwNJSUhnGpu3NI2kk8zlVI/W1Ey@FThWUkSYS2x3c5up8s@RymZJBYQvFbeqe30D3ai5f47u/WSOg0Pw0g8a/OlYpjF5jqgTM08216IXwdZ6BnO3F6pt59nlf82LoJPVpOJsyRJJC@SF41kC0A3GvHZKrXWLPu4pC9c96DlCiSdIOnQViwn/FS86OALye1EEmf2ie@/AoKm9UCbdXTswRefq8BkEo4bObjjAEd5QYzK53HeOiE9H/kfqCXt4f5j5653z@QSzbXzNRfXJJAqz0Dy5JXzzpdAgYXaSpJmLTGp5cKJX6VeF5RNFY86K5IKCAA9pSDI53XGyerUo6CCz@VXv5ObbJbArsoK2FU1n1HrdWUDRNDE6PLTHwbelJztvbvzgCRxGvknf/59tfiTP/8DunQ@eUGnllWtmICQaFQKxcTZ2ejsDATAC@aXT7QS15YBtgBNkqKXixtitUKkUqm8IbalBEMniMpFJZ3whUS4oaKQF1IpRVLTG1pJToPPeXicVEqVS2CNlnhQJ76Q59OJvQMrryrbm1tQsi0tp1bXGg1eiUfDSfzbNP1ygkuUHj4/JwQsRr3b71sqNUlS2IZeCWTzlbAJb6jhV8IaeV6r41pGBQ9xiVYLbOABELh8J1nPSBtJAno2qTcuqhetDF1yQEc9nm04zSvIaK7hjuFFpw0HfuaGT3@mSa3UwQdrZDM3PvT51EZakrpd2ufgcg9BqCcYybZNkq8DvWxIkMuNaIUA@wlCM3351d9W1cJP/vzXztvn7fdVVS2XywVFTfzsZ5tjZ@yb3frPIOKT6OA@ICLD6iKxHrnHpuOL8XgD7egsB79BZjnxOAVhx0BaYazYIBo8lxg7qIux8NGoBY5PEJBHrb5jduloBXeC0jSt1jY7Kq@bosE2CCgjWarL0bO50lWOi/Qcpqt5fSNLYZANPDK60UpzZ9xb6IVbY0Hfq3JvzUCBwxCkMddo@/bYG9Gd1ikaT2llyW2IAim8hccQrkHoNAn7bAG4MPTT16KyLPsUa1TeJni6OR5qCKII9xZECY@4t6dkpHu@SUNaDsgJIgah@aQeXdxa1YK0bRahTV1TtPQsQJaw3LFIDqhw3FsgW1IsWCByEmsTAlSBp7wFCIAypELAVotsEi1NzqxMpjo7MfECz8dxXEBhdKQfh9EQWhfQFEeuYjhwAtURv@OLdBHWMPC9OccICIPB1u/VQPnE6NSGwrwF5DB5Y1AA63SANUSLRm7fnuWqVrO6aUJLhPCPrRGO1dJ6cJbnFYBFWvwtYKkgTmUyWNlvLZIdYDxDswtUJ7BDKKtzUQmP1guOg/8bEy1S5JWqoh5VLEBYX6xVGIAyiIxoZ3VokM0aUdRimsSZNyDvBs0UPfApHppoTm6J6vuR5wXk8GeJ6JNcwKyO5se/Q7q9a9rnw/MY4T4BBWxMj6kNBjpjBl3Ttoa4MBBHq5Hp7QdR7DgWFMWyaeie5YEaTJcJRichpjQljdFmJ0fSfNDtjGqO4G7DfBpfNBaGJvDW8WS@MJ01KroaLlSoP3IdepRfgKwJd3UCRQCPggQeuYHJsj12TvE7eWHd0MjzOYJSgpaDlI85pkcTuo7ps7i42q7jmfpxhJssMfsiMYZdopZJihKag8tKnBhcmkaiGe6A9oQ47tjmELJ0aJr0wAO/Ikl9EPrGHZwTlx5aQFeDexZ0P44v3WUIlk6tY0s6wjPRBbeH5yJQ4AAF5ERsfmy9HiiaY7tLbNc9JrZ1bLJpjdT8sYj46ZFCFhSfLGB2dgNiKyjyqloWB8GULAsFdxFeRWYsZefirqWm6etvTVlLtbFGz2kPZkGt2OaJ7szhl17nXDiQ4k99jp4CWSOoOKTALsYsF1omO1AtiWccJtMi4L4LEhatXx@iYEwRp8tGKT7Bp0V/ZFsBNXIjzzwhOBDCYR8DTNNoh1nAVgylfYt2ALTtQcvCkxkDrwI1l4GceN2UAU0vZPAOuUU0lcOAkDIGZRkAGFj1tUXo4AdRsRx@0IWKEekcEfIVaJ3DLvjhyW8h@WH8iLrRTM/JnJE3WQvBYadD06oR1iwiS37Ogq0D6ZkWfQ08C5DDJTlZS/EZAJvh0zwDHce/Gp1RO0d5SYVch5QlCCFENUChooKOLAdPip770B0uIrmjA3fGbxkg1QPRn56eivQQ0rFniaaPH3/zXUe3pVHfAnHYlQJzOAo/j20Z0iiCOzMJ7NuO4mgw2pqgUFsr356yN8f1/Fq4/DaV7PlJ7BxP8Ntm/eEJ6laQ4Z5PCeqeRb9/aKTC5cCM/tRW9iyiv0qSnuiXvEAghCCYSXaaNbIALNsxjrO902419DihDRKAQy2akSMeDexFlqEfmaxRLw7hBshHY6@OfUzXEwAkns0WzJJmJYxCTiNraB9ZuG7fMU/Jjufp0xT1T2NoJODUlIo9ZArdPvUBI3Qz5IydU2tN/p/2vn4/bSRZ9O/oKTo4GZAtvhzbyWDjWWxwwq5jcgAnk4sZVgaBmQHEIGzDZHx@5yHue9xXOa9xn@Le@uiWWkLYTjIfZ/c3e87EQuqurq6u7q6qrqpuLduh6gu/OmxqvkcRLOQp3LnuBcpJi/H7gr8v4PuCvy@CRlWzrUWbRTJ8dYfdQa7HAARVEsEsVZk7TvAbfCHIIIeLPIPAksvQO3RT7haptqI3/4JxLCrGAJ6YAsGdVLb1w0Xroj3xnNvN9lZ2AMyeIELAiAPoVptoetvzn5H6o5vR1PVCr2D7IPFG4o2vuleSG5hXsI/@ABFjML2GmJR1MJaeTiwQyA4DBJTD4COKBqV5amju@1my6SMwTisR0JgRa0lk2iR9yU/yHYhLTHomrA6orQHC936XAE34ItTM4as@1erwYeZCGVU2TbcTwhK5FMl2EigZmSq81uzTIGlYpdMKTSA7iqvFaFfUdxiKVuST1s07Of46@k8/G/0@zIt47IlhecPYN/SpgsEGIELI6UJUFYdFbVwBg@ymPXJmsHNVWD6VuzU0s5lVaga3g13wbofz7lVKG/yuyeNDWS0Sk0TBZ4VlsQhdXBZ5WvK8UCRlgvvVPFltqRhB1ucFBGDkYqs5stpCr7YoFnnhEIs11W41JBeE5IKrcOnFGiTbshpoT1W1veDwtEE6xSiIBMDL8zYKYtA0ITz7xkEPjh@vx1PUqlSbwZpDXCB5CEVs5LNuO7b1loa0tmhFACAjrgDo8S3gBSO64OXT/i9/jWJSqjWKf0k24LUCGIyW4H2DdSCfyUgHBoE/sUX7AMzdxFbLSOTpmCBv5WXOjnzCUi/Vf/nVl7lwyXz4Zc6K/N/v8rKNlNUmqCZ95HM7uCAbgaVCN1m8dUEbDOwQmsOE9goPisLvYAGYUDHW4MYIJUWK273mBbIv8BRn9sCPJEUFKycsUVIf44XGSpx7lNybGhGU2O0W9IyLScLc1@4XUFaGYGMU4qR6WhGbFPDSJ8FZCc2JWYKlFEbj6XByHwJ0skeSN04islo89wrwH@BgKZBAJrJfpIg25oO4EUUur/styowlJwLxqUjldWwQwT4oxxM8WrcSzz2RsL6BiiYybqV2YhrhRP3yiCRUH5DzppMU1LIS6UyCqsI7zEWDkMIgeDTxvUIYUEbZVCliqFDgBXcZutjHWUBXJgOHFDM7m3@V2/vWoN5NrLk1bn3btja7xYSAJciejL3r2W3vp4F7ddMXIzH98XLRXf7ysxC7OwKzeG5/w4GY@b1ilsLGKEBXfJujKxYkgt9RqCmmSM8oc3ZS0OUKHLnwVNBFD4L8FAooE0a4VGyOFReiUWFeHLf22sUJLMLj1qS9j2aN@VZxvpXfSuGLb/ImZlDCmqlua94Gutxps2jTeG2DVoN3borSpUcHn7CnGSFzwRx2SA9PYOngAi9iGg1B0CdmuiWFVEYJgrICDBtA1C/CNqp91OypvIVPUr2HShlRQ8i3QxRK/A8eXtvn0Q6Lx6tzvDEAQOJRF0gYlLAfdtkX26y0OwJ7hKVg1x7oSOCIozkGp79/DUDGkFciGNxV6gsax/DOZIGKK574w05dMIz/uB52fzp@LbZzuZf53Iu8RjK8KBcRzGVe7ATbFRBJfdhGF5/d/I5hHLvTJbvswWaOsHbSCNASp6gcvwe9zLlxJhPHKI1G7Nvn4c0VzuzG6WUMo@70yG308poogmrcNZILtFr3etbl6w4uhxN7tkS@wLtY6IIEmPz4F30Sx6Dq9OXNgJaBVhBQyMbDOdtK3JshXiviW3767mjk3iLBumh0YXpgpbEDe5yxaYowSkgshQvp@@Nrb45TGq3GCNC@xHtsuz4ZJrD5dWFkyIRhjAAUGe60xia9CCbQXndko6qViUMAGtIooBCArvWuu869OBiExGfiIGTHVKiGrUYm684Ml@bK2EbVFuS6gMA0KlRNwx0GuPmm2hCN2knzQ6leEfD8rl57Xy1XyuLoo2i@qYjj2ruP5JAr3tROy5V6Q2BE63HtrFmvHp03a/AiUWpAzQR9MEpnH0Xl@3f1SqMhanVRffvutArQAHy9dNasVhqWqJ4dn56Xq2evLQEQxFmtKU6rb6tNKNasWdSqqmYE9UTtRLyt1I/fwM/SUfW02vxILZ5Um2fY2Am0VhLvSvVm9fj8tFQX787r72qNisCOGeVq4/i0VH1bKWegfWhTVN5Xzpqi8aZ0ehrpaO3DWaWOyId6eVQBLEtHsD1iS9TPcrVeOW5ih4KnYyAeIHhqica7ynEVHyrfV6A7pfpHSwJtVP7jHArBR1EuvS29hs4ZqQeoAuNyfF6v4EkUUqJxftRoVpvnzYp4XauVidaNSv199bjS2BfGaa1BBDtvVCxoo1mipgEGUAu@w/PReaNKdKueNSv1@vm7ZrV2ZsIgf6jgrS/HJahaJgLXzri3QKRa/SNCRTrQAFjiw5sKvK8jTYlaJaRCA6h23NSLQYNAxKbeTXFWeX1afV05O67g5xqC@VBtVEwYsGoDCwBMbPdDCRo9p17jOAFe/AjMaijOtWg4RfVElMrvq4i5LA0c0KhKbiGyHb@RNM@gc60moA3xLkbHHutCW3/11Y2DDmGr0l68/OefPx3XyhWRUOeGieDDOew6ryIHU/o32Gn8j/AzdADQcy6vBx28cgcldr8aC1Vjb2BhRgcTI8kvjHvOqaXsRhU2Njqd96VOqf660emY1mNqhtB4qAalVgVh7Z5SpuwjxpqhDQ2FykKB6X4QItThNygO9p2ZJdgJmUoy9b@hzXVij0FXzGZ7jqyGphAErMRS2INn7lgAsB4ujWSFxdj3oEmSeuj3ULIDVUwp8JluB15jz7mQ68E/k1@DH7w5aC9gdWZROpsdOHNGAxRU1Qw3QgYm@kfad0D7Iknec5yfBqmc3pwz6ZkZvJ8KvSNlHSo7d0ajQcp8oPqlM4hUT0frE7Jo1FQJkz0OLGDtAhmTz8EkyYQcl8yMepbCfzpz@mMqbNiChoYSaopM8FIhSn3D1Vu5NpKVDYUgUfMgo8z3tvR99QMqubntnf3I@zf@e55b6DCIvqWw4bWoXpv@vGlzAZhgZNkEkgylvTGb1eqAWEYCpV/4FgpeYSG@Xwv36iuH9nUgCQiy1/ZIbxN349lwoWMP6/Dreunt0fnJCSydiO3Oq92Xe/uGf4j5vcV/P2I75N1JZ7hT2MdBTqNP2iw5BsGHZormih@wPzFwNosFMZBDDRq9RKuZf4kVCwmcA4NkqQPsroeJICZoBkk4E7p4i8yZTw3Fr7EzUzJAKtRVE3szthck4tsgKxEPyEPT0ZJGbYH/IGx/@qsp7ndIMpBkMfJ3Bc41nvC6l8BKdNLWd68nfAyCRTIJxcd8KO7TAG/lEvmCPEakX5K3tVEEwRYHGucrDTvVBCSeRrEQUg8lz25o4h1ZbaVySWex8OZ7yW/w@FG6C5DzgO3NS/MGkPHEr4k6cKDoyk63JOQ2BtbhEbVq6UCgBcGUSNHck6qqb2bVZgOhgjGvaJ0KA973rbLRJlERTv4tCfo2cyqaQhHOvuRY@Rs4N647Esq@ssbK38rGJxiWbzJmqt36bRiqyEffKqjIGSLTV9GD4P@JNImBfwAaJ0APqKW5VDyKkgSVaQXqKxFleKuMGJrlJKCm/upjAOZOH5grv2PSMrQgVwIkgRydpXrxkZxI@qkYAiCTm@hZoM3fnuvQTeSwM4Pq9LeEKaujDWbSHU9TQu4VaqtYgZvea1skdlnKboM/TGGSYVZoDZ5CVfE3VtwuadaDyhRR5cVzL8HgTGVNzW7ieUYw4YlLkSJ5NdkDzsrJWabWAXlwpW04Pf/8CcTSu7UWwU2hORyF1n5pVVOEAtCHiM9qPynC0BXdkes5Ef8VvgOiST4F6LlvyasTpQMAehqgixPCed4T8lZCZ36LG8SIoZPjQwBNpJ6T7wU2wscSgeCgllszA6SlbfXWx35B2N9q2J9POL6EfhaEKpFhHxOJ4QSvlQSeoUu7xVt7CSiPHtdtZrHsZsO1xK1DUTxslpD1MeCy67ozEB1t7DfgaA2XZkZ8kEYHZ@Jdz6Q3COxnw5m0SCihH5pBsYm1d9pmOG6DUPOGIDfM0eaC/EFdGjv2RDqIDBfpPZEC5lU8eogsTG4ti628SB0EXw6AJuTkRUQ8EHuYYI1KMUGlA5ZDFBx6vnIBs8Tldg5ELph@t@7sJ9z7UQSa9Jye7@elgYQXapCqE/KY6c6561PXI4sGDAVaQHxK5NmQdml3f7pFyRv26JeSnUBAx1eJwNcIPcGoJ5/fjs@kEio2FDCubB2Yby8Ng4lU2paOVr7rVX57l1CJU7ju1ipj5HsVNomLxMXEX1IK8u7X50p0xCdeN/2nj/jEd/85xecezh54g/ZzKYIiwiizos12dZ0j/PC84sPQmfV0myhIMj17iuY3Un3cCfGiMh1KJ4quPfecJWgA3exwkSUYndTf3atJ59gd2YOhO7RBT8PQigWvePi4pEccsMHMvfUolpiTJmmFesvgmazh8lAbf0uPHfwZHHR6c2ea0o9A5rNlCfMsoBZDx/h41urvV8Tf0@iJs19nZzeo5NchPDLTa@8KdNP9tXVf5OMq82kBApAL3GHkdIaOyR30eSyqltxpSjvuUAUu7yug4Xgp0sLWPt@txfhbIBEd8IYwVsisHHnonUDNbC3Grd7C6pFHx8ydw7pVdjBm1UvRa8vGlJ6winyHpxAFkX@V06pSvszeAr068GG5ntzbL/9k7AGBr0A//yKOW@IYgZa4vpwNsCaTMiF9tgAXcmce0hpNKzGsYsMB7EKjENDOIgo1/Hm5jhp0qghCkXRaWOFKnJEpUHww5UWqA0tOZ0k3pCdF0iRHARRBSnRhzjqGdXRm1f1r9HbwiJtD7DK4MB1LyCkN6XWk6gKVMBlgCOb0WkeZPVQfnjHb248dtQgBi5KAIRy0PJmphJJc0BObb6Oe07GWO4PFOBGhnjyVTHpzd5p8JPXWrh2x59xxtO6a64j0KcJsRdgsN3tE2uISH5f7RhSfCNOEKUan2MBDqL7Ss8/mUSIuih2cb8XO8gE6rKNZcCbrbyr@ePd47uOmeINhpWqj8acU4Y4uX/v@@1YHOt5Zv4JImKxedWjF6OCS0VnyowYqQiafSo@nEHGfxD1Cjx5QDtvtAe308VlL1OgBvHIgU59CLkNIT3SDt8cOrkvTfgY6kjLV@ZS/SPkC58Ja0lFePn2JLpv4gQGiVOykAzsUW3CDwYrwEcVa9FMddAvM40oET4fss6s8nySiPsEoxkEad9i9t9VZpvPtfYa08CGBVsHXtN8DSb7CYq3OgqCskAKmeAwp/B6trE1Xj@/V1/YFygEErk2fvWs8ggdpCjtjii3ABv7RP3UWKAMHTcmaoRkVnggdWhpgLoCWMhg5rK6i9DecMcfjPT5yGoECwa/plp8tWQOdo/dyPrWxyqK3xCKmJDfPNhPzpFGVgKH4N5JfTkUWdUlxBQAOYwz1i3mAgE5ihD0eCoyc/jzEeSFE5RhBxWIepyW8JB@zwIck5jsSVRbY2dVK5OJKfKvDSMcCAcEivkyACMgs8UUCKLDRxeKilXgZ35@gBAjEiveZ4jAUclTCNPRHjglIOfRyZrCitPLCykkOpo87u2boo8/f9PXbnPY1F/0K9PExbKXz0a@vcqGvoWa3t8NVQzWBHqbeaugjkMLUEfZXha/7n0EugZoDuZJwDzQlIyRlSN8vzHEIWibobZkfPXGAJo5DJWMoeHQYl86TqqjUrw4HrIVc3O93ZxdJOjJAT/iv7q2K2VCYyMiL5MWEHO3ZuMsKIUmsCdzqsVuo6ZI3BRpOyOME9Ful07p98b55cqIrweJyqRyNxs5sN5fLIRNf6qEEym8LTUlDNxsune1fj0bZ6e3fZ@8vs7T2Y7bskecWlAbtwJDApPAy7mzAcTaIAxTF0mkg8Ni9cVDXv@739YAWPKHEwYNh45LsK9YTtAENfaeX900Orj8JNth/Ygexf/8U/uy7tVnQlFDUMRTUBupd3CTU6RmQB1/00ffLP6kiYLgwK28m2LfM4uEn3EEwTowGi5xBTTQLSfZPvHFGI9cSHzAb2dMEWVQiFU5O9Ao5LoInjEgUdDEaAYdZwrkZjoLzKQ@L6LyO4NTGpKJ2lJc9RhrUnUFlMU0lWj8kYFuBLm9hN7fQ29cSiUHClK73jwDLfAhoP6r02J6mukSnaGHY6uUMDp4Aoxd5K1b3CRUxySYmafZwaSRqPLqZH93hBG/TM0kWUJEBNLzUkzXFfeImLhb5PtIwxzAkTnRH4KNq3O1/3dL4dcvizbzff9yqSEEVPLCftSJyXNnXLYh0BkAzUE4/oCdGV/4jDdP6JBIIxQIOhj6trjtYoYMVDON5t/jzbapUKoln060tUSodwQMm@TkqiTK@ODoSZcyggr@/KW7v7u7zmls2P8HLI/XyThwBDL6LuHs1K8NP@FbEADfY7kmLfJYtPrP2n3WKB4f7XrZVOmpnswN44rulsiX5Ay@dyh7Rj9YPfqFMJpN91v307Ju7ffzdKreTzy5bz6bt5GAfuQzIULqeu9V52g7cRzOzS2ODdwHtLfmRKj3bwyyusqpQ6RHG9uwnWF0KYqPrZTfkW4/jcGmN3eg62ntngklQQIVXIRxRVd7AEPmxvURzPIxO10EHPNhvKIUr@YFyfT5bUYb7iasV8E9VNggBKbPeOAAaTziW0EluGOMH8LJlZ4IW8BuSebl7hmHD3@G8I/k3@4O882HzIiU2c2LTEpuJBP3B@x82L8xn2SHeK8LF/JshgqMFdDMU3pAEPdIfKHIxQm7DeEYBkAhJhUNT4cn1@BKNz0r7w/BJGb7uDYwndPUom0jokAmrbHx6NrmDYfkEJe4SxhMKZ8xj3g8WFDpSi6HGtBMVf3xRBLI9dgQIWh4zQQouNIknfVCZz/yy6o0ca4NiMwkwkrX@@oTmPb6AvegZxXTmI7oUBo1S8CO/xb1xn4N3CW38wu0HCNCBCquTOQobSW4k8ayDrhbwe0ndFBTjqfdPMh/7OiydOVYMmv9PoTEBfXqiE@7ZhN7ROSZ9ZPonhv7xitZUgstStD2fzBhalfH1aD6cjuSZF5EIR85v7Y5nEo4oAWI4HEFdWJ1hZCjAzAe3DoUh68PCocdL0XOx6zwTZKpVnA5mhk@ONCJkf0jB3P41MrfN7BAxUezAPEBI@a58fXs48pDkc5WzdWDPLjHXAuVnFsM5n5uRPQ9z6kQwdvs@0hmCTC7nwXyGrmxMZ/ZgbFti48xtzuxlFbYtkHzm3YwJPZwk54QETj7ZdFz3FMLcIzkkRBG/K@Q5hNHbo6UMNuexxdGgwaAhVVNBJmjASRBiJ6Kk82torCJ0DLj6MwZBR3ll8fZPI@USSysvehpJSEEX4B@aZitTx1At6HPHnzgJg1H1Z6biBVnpGjfaMR38wkqOCb1V21TTkeeDApZLbB93p4EzsUOb03RkGJyY5Fl2X/C@iPOZEnuwN5K8ryj/Mh/kD0CsQI78IXx9MO9Nbp9lNuNJKvXkwpPB8Rv6PoLCc8b3xc/ayKryrJzCwceUkO98MuTFMrJDDZn2wIQZUSXPf4DQH9kDwG95ay@RFS82Ut89zZqtHy4m7c3UxeTXi19MwkQuyWqXTYsNeZitViw5V2BnzFqhn8orzQMSYO5EcTEJF7iYkFsXn95LEgAi2VTrh2z71ywgdLFhmpvZiw0mSGjIEJPs/e1lEXx2Bc2NMBbZDeOJuWmqwU99lzcF7K30F8eQX5j8F7BQSiWZ6UHPmfUBFMUA0d0EqNhlX23ndrbzO6AJDZxFeuZc436b9q4vnQWIEh6qs7D1XPwS4oYQIe4Wnr0PLxfQz@FggmmgaUQ9mdBCLqFymlM7hs9WUCfDPAHlgcopJAGGuJh@GRsPH1HhtwSwnCpLGS3YdVDjvhTun547xnZsD9e1aHQIcyR6GbCPCJlQ0whZMt5aDjXVdElSsFlGHF85MMgIBIY3u6HtFhN3kpbCmplJ7qMQjVEzI8zrG52jK1M0NEOfSWEq@VTkD797@d//u/bzxnzjcDv7YQZ/5xs/b@y92uBHeIBfL9Svm43DjQMstne3scyCDgyPL//7/0D9w78DHPyyPIB/DncVrL3lxmG6SFV@3Tjcg4f89ja0@3//67@gD89YY8PMNs86liDE9hVFju0J8S58F1XsJaulyWBZyePCgjDYwxB0c/iBjlGL7Vc5MtNtSK@KG3T/Gfbnvj@K3OLJMWtOrkJsyVD@FCAZcYUiNpBmkMqFoi803w3ltoHMG6Ap/vk8s@eBBvBP6c7hN@m7bjz30GXoGatFMIApbhH0eX44zH2X8N07CgnlU7KvREhU7eRa@@rFPrDDO9eZD7thLwk1Xcdd@9a5zCAfZpzeNehUE2/k/jjL3gBLjvPbr7J9NO5nyY87OyVI6eky8wsIgjIbCSiG5HRqiRmMgDuGv/CMOUpAoD/xz6RUdg6QsqdOl21Y4QxPUKTRLFfqdYuPh7E7mUCUTtG/IMBjHhKZVkOLPL@YQM1avSASW35BLkc6r4nYvCPnWJl0JM3esJS9FgQY6gNaB1V/MqXZgIKQqNYMIHCRjN3rdWz5LWU8SajAc8t4cuWMpsUE@YZBb/BWNZDQJf1ZzFwLJT1EC0I6TQsdwho7cxtU9GKC3qA@HrQwx9sJ@KyVdGNaXXyy9mVZqdX3iid4pnVP07fc9C2MKEoJQTs@zwS5cCZCL8ZrSxFNlTOng0dqsQ1Da55KgTXL0B/EwONhqfYxLEF2hyIggWpBd6RXmT5sFunCwCO3DsfssWmR84AZG0Hwo6VKAGdVzzIoO2G7GW4MFogzd@IU0EOZb7/DCIiiStoynJAAtPJZxQ5LMNSH2tRhNBWhsCOW3JYmsB@SwIGxlAJIMHQ83tQCH2yDdw8ftISjJfRJoOElYSJL9QukbFFBNRwFSqrFjaNmxnaqVlf4yXr6MhcQ3euGLxK5/PaLnd29l6@@xZjxJ7K38WCwUga1gOmVDTBIok6Bko3vi8VEMsGvMKHXapMIPQ4sHsChW9etSVjx41O8TICB5RIE65YSU3F1aa4kkAHEmZPBHQF0lNQskUp9V2hhx9oXPfNX@C9hqdrMcGhqtkfDX2wmvTYO7zgggtIcjZ2xO8PjcVyYbcrsgjn1YQvhL3pZx@3XHbyzCn1dme2hoVPXxaCEmXs9uNK5I8PWftGECQMEn8@WBdKgXjscKUo6tYYVyqLS4FDVoi@KCl5rtQfolItbAsp8DBymGUwG9PK3pacpzo4kbEKY5wEjVvEIUXMd1dmZuHPiispZOYqYzIQ29Hy4Gd2zFYQ72A8BfKV2gpmPtO42gbowJQay12pNstigT7qvXOByWA64ApkeY6W7mNZLo4paq0lumKfuI0ueeHHoJ7QLqsI4Il4xMPO5h0mp4lpVL5AgaiGU1iR/EbP88xydZAFO@iDjPEVeThQ0H9G3Q8@jXN6ysYQpPUqpEAykx6cScQDRbpNLcEdyBRxReqxQGisebb7slVwm8X5UHmBfU3ViSw770lRAUeOcWcSnBfa/enZsiXIF/jn5ULZQUD4q/QP77SfMWo9vXuKbL4jqiRoCIqg0w5HPLfpM/YwhSsAsOYvTlwQI4uJLhg2sR5I3UrBSPZG050ndCs3tdsAVyK62FMKVdVROEsyaQjaQJ1J5J9OZzLUoFfoCG69WV5otWVhNCzZx3T@xNZo8CVr1ITEpHwFiOwoirUAE3P4kYHj2QCfJ25a6i2Ls6kk8T4dYlhUqENtPskD2MM@upcx9bLEt2WK7gON4H18Q397LG3xvWZg5HuCNp1/GG@nHM0f634I5Kn8Od7yQ3PGigGsPc8ekO3NoRaKITkpq58ZwzOWS9uBObzgYon2or/3ETuQsDQAteHQdmU3xIPkc9m3NciJS8R@2ovsROglt7@4ZX9j5Hdn5nQKuufRYdv6ndj79G3d@V3Z@t4B7TczIS9FOhr/@dj0ORMJU@EXs8KK4y8XML@3pnuzpXgF305hh/sN7mv6devpS9vRlATMm8IEDp3C9n5tZEik1jqvVwN0iozIQpzArYDxXmqh74ZXYluiPrr2rIkrr4ovxfyXxf4WrET3Vkay2FqPs6/KsnnKwPEuWfGkeBllxT7i/MtRL76/csAJ9RG5QvEiTYWsmFRUQyC3@GJw2ZQL5MVh9/c3nsTjz2k65lTgzrKZAs0aYN4MpzpIvFVYJWJ8wI8/RknbcrJ9u/S8mw9j@SUahAfI4tLd4x5DcSXQVDMeKX8vOaN1B2A2pc4RYRZKTkJ3LaG@fXZ6sX9UosUVkX4xXEviojdMlYwYqR/MAIpMR0CYj6yutCl1zlXrBb6DvXCi@y7LHX8Sl30ou/bYg6lIxWEcqWxr8JC8Getr27u59ewDXyuAfnIA5C8rfM6v@X3C4sOr@UeojdTpvHc/b0JJFGXqebi4jsIwIlyldQ5lZAa@LmVyi/8F7P/nUtqFlWwZlxTOM47flBtou7Mtuz@kProY//jSeuNOfZ978@uZ2sfwlnzAMlZw/ZXLWQuV9I80Uq/maE7NEJGlzWsvaHIBAw3ySrSZhQ0gyn0@arUJhu20KnJ9jzsfE5wMBABJRJ94I70giNws/ezgNJXswRGN7PTr69@YYcw4kS43s8WXPFouCQP/rdN4S6A0m33aBkEAissOkurB6Tk3TpDth5JUTSR1yIWnpP/WuzgbjKtvnRCIhUYKfVToQQGOLX9S30LTI5NIWm8B8/GXYC1tK2Cbj15Sp9VAtkHy6vdM2C0CmD/QFGf7KHs35RDD1i@l7wjhzP5IAt85jXuRwF8mZocAFDekD2gD9jpmSOYJTLu6vtq6Gvmvt@DBaAfh2qHCIVtqPLZj6fugOAIOp4B657ugUx1e1YElqWOJV0JkgEyKGNb@xR31/FFS24iE7VYZ4J9xHyiGL1A4NTIQQkhh9f6ULgqmvsFlXWor9@njYABhfkrvCCigdX6y0UmCFS2gNDeX0oU0jWo@H15tzOvGYTgTM2fKRoBzRAb9p7zfE97U6jP6NPRuiYYutbXloI@NkYH4OyOF/LidTbKIiObm2d2Fe@ZBphpkryMX3aR3KqdWXoPfKl9gArTvYAbw4V3UBd7MBZTd8GOlHoHzPdA5xKINF9j6B7chnb8XU@T0p1CWTiLSUH@OmXZi7kbVn6GOcehUZbEUHnF57SC71os3ySvD5FY4z5hyDPWBmszvZhjifD2ERXwY@zSTckMOYLmVREiIGxrn5oxO4e2WJS/lD5teRmGqLB9KG8vRfmUGi8TWdU8Ba7I6xJV7imTsxhA8RBDicAXkzbkXExvyfWbFtru8ulMJ@equCZaTLoUGN7657rSOQe7CfQXn1BHuIvo6vEGLYDrPAKgS11ErXYdwb5KdVzsYjqU4Hc/90OpRqpdNB@aHTSXIrLExoQpB270Xpsnc9S8/sq7FtT/6e7XpeGi/dns4NowtkPTgQycpZOYmhVv6nzHQJ45DeTAuZp1@QyIFvjEQiHGV63GiIxnG9@q4p6JtBY9J1RyNHigdSRqrNeng/aHnYnSuxiaU89WtsY1ohgy6kFMee1yBcuIc4uJ0Ouv93OinPGfW10dkInuC/N823p6JJCQeblQblQ2zEFEUYGQyAJPUUET94Wq4dNz@@qwAVx6ND40D9gUKHVO9gPpyPnMODLP/ld958iaLAcuqAFijfZekl1M1y5YNLt7eEP73hjaBPxYQ6@i/MHBC3hjfOPlTWaUsI9l13HiCYhfoIVELLMoKqgl4ZBLlauSYKwu7hkQ0Igkp5wEnlYWDIsL8UyRfJzNAjvT5lhluWN59IaTTJPzPYYtISydutZMzWHx6IxpsS0PL1ae2odIoZv95V6pjGct1YXA46wDQowdK1DMnwVw5PcychoYK@zKXEGv0YLvU9icbhdx/D79Z0o155XcV8jusxZ5IWxadcIX8X/nSDPlWxX@gSCvp2t4rBGlROTkuv78UClbqVfY@@ooU59uuapmpnr2uYghJTZ65r0Z0MQNMYdLDlGPKqz9h0By/q8B5Fb9XyUa18D80HI@5MtFFsDKfHo5o6rp2frV8cpItwPgxlw/ARPW@@O28a4Zr@YgUThtYpSyy0pUqbWtInZWGug39UalRE5ZQynmqfyNdl5IwVdEssLV5UQAWltdPxQHSxVKJCFGMK0bhmulY1djmyL0F/vp47@xgHWvh0N13sz92pfMCphjl@Cxzrmvp013MG5v6F8ekuwW0XE8DQicNPd7xYXUySfBXNPCUR1SfzCt4@0qYRIUa5Uq@@r5QVPRra51BJIFr1WH316dUdzroYN6dRjPLPWDL7TMwIpVY2YfpClGcISQLBlGEw/Ix@V4MZetWmaZLD2/1LFzc/2IV7w2uvsJt7vu/TRSKy0hyDtPTFMZJ0PUZOUB1G77I/sbu/WeeoLwi7fm@HQKwFrfRyhIkr4L/R797BC0OO6KU7n7vjNKW1VsPLtULfcTKFPvsAYHKtr40fY6pGe/Il5F4h2aN4S00zSu18Uj3mTb4BUn@pXq99aERWwxW@tGcz9/Z8@vuwpsipcYMnSUFaxQTSTcC6NuyJC4NWMbrAbu7PS66lFYspxEMpS10YXE5ndtQlCBMzu00XEQa/vmoyE9HK7u3kX5JsuHv8rjQL06mOlf44QgW9u4dOIc5ZSyiN5n84d51C2/@SRNNZ8Hei2vo1j1K237vmBQJMs/J9Myq0IPnpXmqd8vjiywi@uv3qXQsEQmphDXtIfH2049W3e1b4/nA0Wif4@ireYlVelhLlmpqa@rdYJy/XK43a6fuKKFdfV5vifen0vBIRm2d4NnTj8EG2bGrmDPBCCKAfnVBpDSc1BaKLoRUUB8fnWBTshqfhaDPq@wZNS/QdDgcZzpMelzV0i6qf72fiTpzYllQTgV5eiEvxFAUN1ZK/JtF6RV/CdW7xdtCihCsPhH5NmlHTOxSTbj1JNMxwsAR52@J1q3iP5apBeCRtaDxKIfoGlEXA@ba5ughdPbb2dlxtSYrIUSFINFdmxDwf7pwHit1q57ZXOwcE@6ruSQTRrpWBRlMA737Muq73hyMGbT6MGGiFfzTVMKolRDkzosuvnlCQC8I6LpENt2gWhE/DZNDbP5wlRVKthXGmJu3KigLL2oPryWOmqH6OGhykLp6iEm@tTGDzoSl87I5Whyy/tn/J2eASdHqL/t/0d5HYs3jrvksu4o/vrTWn@vcBMu8Z7tilMLIpVM/KlXeVM7ySRvyj8vFDrV5Gk3AjujXIi98jQ@h7YpMJ1dNtzrqBVVXgYpSNYu6qe6JAjrkSI7cLswJHgoxltBMvgqNGBs/BL/Agb14OnRSrg3haJsickQxTYwUGs4lYXefpmJk7hOB2VvmBMmneN3m5Ol5PsVJ3@ci6@Zi6mJ/@sW1vr6n/2PZfxNUnyywbi6S9CjHiP8s1QrS/XupDhAaYdQN0/yRfGT7z9x1A8e83gmT9@srxU0anP2oQX/01iP7/LmePrLwTV3n0yMq7MZXnj215L67yY1t@uZZxfVPnKvdaImqx@wx2lna3v1akP2lFUnbP@xal@EFDu99fw/ZnDhtZXj9/4MgQ@dfI/Zkjx7bgzx86tIb@NXJ/5siRPfrrJDg0REYGkQykUfxQdY9iF26H3SvQrkkAwh/vEyHRohlBIbBmOqlHkMl8bGOoTn6ZQvilut6XMho77aDVW5qthfJYl4xVaK/rddh7433pVLytlasncR4cKwTynD9sSm@Tou@TLbDk4kfyvokzms06bFp@NFVFLBB0EvTHHMP7YycZ@iW1VPE22YZl@zGu1uwv69czH@H7LD13b2cuxp97eMOSCvEe23ONA307SqmMlyqf1s7rMLD1xmdM9J77@wysO11LRzZxfgn337CDvloDo5zkL648qaM9k6UQM/i8lYx30NZMnRRL0x@5doAavcUk9/x6xfQbbiP9NW2kH9fG5te0sfm4NrJf00Y2G9fImmWpXDk6fy2yovGm9iG@DH3xrvCCKLzdqTtznMm6JSy8hkGd34fXYy3nf5oVMLJD@KPhz45IpQft93I5@gmkE/8eC30R0gaHh49HZzhRKZQfNTx0AdofOD6fs1/EjRFThY8pflN6rrHFn9XO0mSADxni@Q5737NVN8l7HiYJlFZ5z72edfXzFEpNi2PEX4LMtKmVyKl7dzC8TSnsQMshPhjnpfI9UOirUJlE@W6QeL5lx9QtGPDYRgI/3K9pxPdyXWkntDAp8YS482ISv5nE9z12sQy8nVsrDsDtVhIxSrYVQxIhYsFs6IDS6TRW@ZRkRk0WPt2BTEig4PFuPR4xHsCxuMZ6Pa@UXO/LvMr3QfPmWoKujHMsvEjIiQ981XXaXBM/5k8EmaM5xB7yHIkuj9Avkijce@S2CKVyDtcWSUuP5FlLTj5OC2RNSyxgCcJ/4xb8R7uMx06Exw1wvGO4dk0ZXSZsrJ1HtNyP1OHqRsxcioURrhYnseHJLxA8ntprNkeNr1eCEYkjpBbAZ@wrx4n3cT5VjWPrB079I@tDXykWwcTG03N/aieTd2vWBp5jVN@/PAGpYgHRzbg4RR23w3WoERKk7XiSLqBnri@JhbR4pZS5dvpOKetcAH393JI78RSpcuZOnC8gIf99kIgxHBiewL6/ib1iI9GUMj7aJrEiTWIFBRD5Z9yUnZBQ/VqeDrPrOnRYRyyJeqVUFo1mXZycnx2L6lmjiS9qJ/ThtHpWiTnVWcYPi779KYK3FLXbQerHR6@8YUC8If4rrcKkzSuCy7GXnm7E7P7YP8DlD8wxon0oWiuOsihexhNWjVDhYRrEV2wB7HagiA/b9wIack6MfwMuiKfG/XzxoDagaQQTV3jXmNQLNxNnATqIlzQfu0a1Cju8LOFe/RvtlJqAELtTrhc7YhajOGl5jT1PXYnxGQPHJKT74GNkC6lmqlsyjLXzjgrk19j9AjcnuSBEPZxCwxPR30pHsOqWjpuVsnhbab6plRv@p4gzL8bpRqN0V0PftBBcMxKcn7x0BteTaIwphb5Neo@EzLGzsWGtGcrVFB/ymumOXKDRCkZ0@3tybbTecen0tHR0WpGkiQbsLZyu1GMx529nas@voj1gNVZF3PrFYLefJSPZX14lo@jpECLdosGIvAvp1rJepAgS2jQeijzneHFA2o/Xlk0FiXG0chmmQ5DaxjQws6hhIBeIdFek83pA@lMt6piu05Fp0/m1hemRJs4tTTXbT0pr/E8I5H5keGVORlfm4oIrcxRbyU79FBK9H8RYJg53crsyHvyhuHAmsUx1FA7yF1N3tByMXHiGB6B4tufcZCfXo5GBW35v2O@HB0F/PvxmG2/EdLpXrgBs/j8)

[Python 1.5.0 source code.](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/src/python-1.5.tar.gz)

`len(dir("")+dir({}))` is now used to separate Python 1.5.0 - 2.2.0:

```
 ver     #      len(dir(""))  len(dir({}))     sum
1.5.0    444        0             8            8  
1.6.1    68         29            8            37 
2.0.0    439        32            9            41 
2.1.0    440        32            10           42 
2.2.0    441        56            36           92
```

The code:

```py
print ([5,0,1,0,2,-371])[len(dir ("")+dir({}))%8]+439
```

Additional `()` around `[5,..]` are for Perl, space after first `dir` is for fish (shell).

Python 1.5.0 doesn't have `exit` global, so `[exit];` solution for Ruby/GolfScript is no longer appropriate (without `exit` Ruby prints `190187`).
Instead, I set [`$_`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html#uscore) in Ruby code and then print in GolfScript only if `$_` is unset (`nil`).

Ruby/J-uby code (`:x` is for Chip, space after `'` is for rSNBATWPL):

```rb
print eval('$_=:x&&(defined?A)&&290||108+[0,0,2,82,-95]["".methods.size%5]' )
```

GolfScript code (`'"'` are for Pyth):

```rb
'"';"#{p 187if !$_;exit}";'"';
```

#### Ruby golf

Ruby now uses solution similar to Python:

```
              #     "".methods.size     %5
Ruby 2.4.1    13          174           4
Ruby 1.8.7    108         176           1
Ruby 1.9.3    110         162           2
Ruby 2.5.0    190         183           3
```

Ruby code:

```rb
print 108+[0,0,2,82,-95]["".methods.size%5]
```

Answer (score 1):

## 339. Ruby -x, 15100 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*'F*Pi26^qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2  #  CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a a a    z     k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz   "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy4iiipsddpsdoh (22)S2&:&echo 335&/ \&exit&rem ]##### #######++(- #### ##-[######;mxf ####xAegguEay######i#u####Ft#######MZWWW####WWWWWW zR###### # ####  #######:_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55  <!--                                   #z#1111#y#y#y#_#         ! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//n&goto e nthteo18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    /112\11  ##### #######   # #    #####  #   #   #    ##### ####  ###   #### # W#W#####WW#WWWW#####W####WW###WWW####W#WW#W#####WW#WWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x########    ## ### ###### ######## #### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### ####### ##### ###    # # #### ### ##### #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \)      # ##########>>###>##>#####>>##>####>##>#>#####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>##>####>>##>#####>####>>>#####>##>#>##>>## ####
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326  #????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?   !?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   :1*23/5%6E2
#[[/]e] x  > >>>>>>>@!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v11cbbbzcbaaaabaca1t@.7.8.2<auaxayatbubxbtcuc11
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}] [328]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [[[
#-  e:
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9
#/*9 999 99 9999   Mn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#   
#{  
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]\'':;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89;exit
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;ppp
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
42::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
:e
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
#!ruby
puts 339
__END__






















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script><script> onload=function(){
g=window
e=g.external
d=document
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
}</script>

<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hatax#8;>0::&&1Pr"9?3"sge>Ex Cr Uithary,85"t."F ._#gi[;s]pogr61k:4op>astd[]!!tfc;[ ]?45:ore>805在ｕ 892g=1*\'ull\0  
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<[[["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};]+ pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"      <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSSbfUt6pULalu3b4UiwWSIIkrEmABoESWpIrunt1et@2Z9fS0He22x7fdM55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKq8iNiY2MhEcjnycyTJ0@ek8@27g5@9rMYPuyZPZz1h7bHPMP1WNcxzwxHZg9m7L5uunktKwgYatvpT0aG5bkVIcZUxoa61Z/ofYP1zKFnOGnmGgZrG0P7HPw1xjYn1sQ1unWwZRmzjHO2b3XMLkBgnn1qWOYbwwG/HGMPjeHl6NJjHXs00q2uy8aOaXnkm2fsmQ6W3qRzyvS26zl6xzNtC7wKjD23hvqo3dUZBR87Bo9UZACqc0pxFn1KjD2xHdeAFOyO4bo2OpbBUXdM@/H204@vhVcz7GMdMjUeGtNryasqe2EaTvd6DI19ery3d901yz6RbIvt3cySmmPbE8/e967Dz7PtvmHpTJPLsnbdswDI9IxhKVPKLHiB357pQC3qfm2xjm5BrWCdbTBjNPZmTOL1rA@HYR26THfZxJ3oQwpnTUZtwwkCup7ueKbVZ@emN2DewHTDeBTaHesdQ@oaQ3NkekaXDU2IZPd8KADa6rJTY3ZuO1C1PkzbGs4gotExeyZGCfIBAPFJeAODwxnpM6hMywMiYDpzIRtDI4CWFGIQ/qHRnvSZPfHGE49B3rqmq7eHALQ9Y12jp0@GXpq1wQ@QSe7nA8PyiRbAyQDi2Oa5@mJCWTPmtK13uywD9Ar5ODWYCVijbFVYNgvuzHYAaxAqyJEPjOiXl9GYQt1AlffsCstnMuC/G7pgbvWha/uZWcwaelrQJqnOEO4zx@47@giw0TUIp5/uP2Nux3bABj8My9vNbWA6usc2N1l89@nDOKuH1SI7bSGsohq7gCqIBZ7sTB9OgEKiNWFD/ThhbAGrLL4Wr7A4oEXLsFyO5aB5lpiWBySpmTIYoJ1rWRV@BaaVWE6FlpKPpzGdnqP3zaHBofQRShEJXMszDd6ZHMuqJR6ybw97PFiHEiuybIkViqyYZ0V4l1lZg9QQdI6p5Tz8CvADaGXIigq/bI4DmtM90CnS2g7r6SNzOPOhE/gOy6usCBAhvypA1koAAb7ZLP6y8KNsLT5R2N4AsD3QzwC8NDRPkesYIePBKlTgo2xsKMT5kLXy5N0BJg@oA6TlS6wIyRcAEznIAmBWK2m8EO7AGA79KAMXo1BOixn4Qa6LgIMSYD4DeMwgIovwAzvwNA2YlwacSgPmo6ngroE5i@AhXAH8ClCNBR9XA909hYR4OlqXEA9cG8CoiGlkVCoiCCBATbEs1FeB5YAIskgE@SyDvENeigUGvKqkslKOlYoMcFnOMKgXFfKFFKICj1QhPyoCg7pXofJVyJMKmFYBqJrNMyGCaDWL/hA3C3EBLWoO4uTADJWmFvAH8YAqVEhShTQ1rTwnQMiblofy5rNEmVoBarYIfoA3DfKqASlpkFutBP4YtwQ4LCHhFuNpjggd8QA1gqQONAjIyEN@CC6EBbNWzHL86cPxQG8bntnhMds9jFrAJlBANELUDBYPvjnEJmQlA2CwBUD2Naj9LLYU4UqARsu74ijLA87wAps7MjBk0sCgbGK/czpMWAGLSQJHXOSWwL6GQI/QRXR0ZGXYsA1iTAEc05MZJAL9pmGfYT9P3GUhGZc4UNvBbh26i67hOAzDgizgpolXuZO2a7yeYIc0z1cPmJ8BPLKnm8MwA9QgdY84KXzjLqQ3W8x2z7FH1GpHyIuGtj1ewfeB850joEf2uTHP@pwx6uPxELofcDd47weZOddJQCFpJpoqzxBEwnidgQkAKSlg26ZjdAj3ftEhdhYY/GIWK0yr38silAeRfinLxjbwbBfjWJPhsAIdhtFh2brSNc4UdOF912KfhXkIejPok3wQbR2EC8w55SKEdE@TqZ88DmrWtUeLReOMaj8s@sDEHmZ4rs@g9nrAo4ypPgIRiKGcYUGvOAKK4TWINQFCHhZrn3VtK@6FUM4dkAag0GFJSOJAnHjmyABx0YYoWOM5yjSyScpZewakTNjKySQf8pxcQ5QsXEcUd8hFHHhjgX6zO@kg1jBt0yIKgv7GRWHJMfQudxM8h52c6PBzoGMc@yKxjAYMeIRZi0hu0KsagH1fhOkQROzsDcsFOcyVmYkCK1B@3@4BsZ2bUHYQkSDqHHaHkIAoCJ2mckcWCOVIQKPTITNZZzxm4A6CB5DnXqYEfbn9hcnegOdwALJYZ@I4MzYdQ02YIwjldexeD6j3jTEeAAg26rLOrAPNEyoZqUfo2sSJOuPFYs5t6waEsVC623n2ddY3AO3Q8/dQnEeSnxdgPKYiECp0i0sFlg6YwiJ0xjNCC4AJY/RsW0b3rm24RCy2cxo2fUzMNfrUNKCd9ebMaIRSDlCpRdJZFziP37wQPiYoLC0MJuVTwceGBU2nA1QJjR6qD@t0m/VAK4nIAiiw6Z2OMfZ8OrGJnZlWRHA62EPBiVwlH5jsDoT1@2zzGtVA0JByIkIBCpKY9bEvz@nIa33VB8QEy5jL7pyzDGc3kocQZ9dSF19hmIUcvBJX5GFMTQKlSGISEw9ZCXJHszNAXughtyHBBVqbM7lZfHCLJu@MmNQL08bcqMB2BFkJnTAfq2FI8BveBCSPhwirvuCAQRcc7gCtu6MlkO0wk8Nu1FVWdBmY4l1AR7ZlL4EKyAzhYpBFH6oLIsYj5Br6MCRGai7uQh0hw55r49iRQR86HtsOtAzOdGakklGVRajL12QSYV@RBE1@sWuFLiOOHb6HvSBEGA9Bf6Mmhi0VRFQdOAUwMa5pAM@zeYqRDFOrJ1h@/s6J9XNigr7UsgyUcnVnxoFA8aB7hoRmzHQcYINn2EnwPijoTGSiU@gTQOdCzorooHZ/PXEZKXpn0jan19WZDjrKX7jCme6wHmoyDggd0IgS8Z4bT1bJnWJGvETFHnsKReVvEQJSIBmqPNED5Qg6iT1gNEczq5MQF5qYmGbixOuVxCQYMCKX0dhX9bF3PXdfgBsSzegU2jXZqqwP3bckwVtCN8oJeigyeugOyBnQCEFkL5e7bZ1dAvcAtXy6Q7FRuKSvKufCtAyrG6blIwLzEi2vzJNwnQ4ZpEivhiXA4FRy6iQWEPiemKCIIjgoit@3ogNJe9yP5BruOLFo4IIluCiSZBehkA8dQIIyY4LwYXZMr@WLK/fuBYLLWq0GxAbSFLDNbjKqHgQjPDJwaggskzTiJyJ79pGHbSORhPJi4CueGxCbgFJrdXbhDRxocWS/EiAQoFWwkJIDxPr1/NQ8nXSvV7SFjhhIxFYHQpPZ8cSqAJ0/bw2127AaX8AqqBBxxCoSL8Yn0DeIl1yxQkU/mGO4KP7W/KxEajiBOfBpdSmKeFTfbU7QO7PO0BcJuAkaO@dGbcj@qT8iEDKitC8TBI32RkvlQLA5cDjs2fbxo5rfFrmn0jatyoLD0O7oQ3Jex@BiEPfx/oPD7cOvt5bAGJrtynUHxcyVCtjVTqZS35ooOVmrrEdhzAE/bN0OGyMuhhEF35tJ9jQiKs060LlMA3QeHH5yHSUgCSE6KAUw4@@aSMPDgNAltHV3cK0TZv1UCpIMowRhmbTPApihAbOO/nqQn2eTN2@w8q5nauy7Y86GE50DCByVfSuIJ6PnNQEs8Gr3eI9IcUEKNS0cmZ2boiGD/HyMUvP1zJAoHSGZjw/2dg9rBNYfpJAoiOJ6IEvpTlcGmh9OuoawLAywPzB1WEqeZxzlacrrUgR3OgsIntctWwEfAKCuI9tMGo6CorkDyPvO9bKRq9QJKYDsBOG6XBmVhzofmtFIPrCL66DKu6wXJY95ZxU6Le2xQt/FbquTzxvFXDnabXXmaXajQGl0FfqBQG50wOvUldBFnkuRvljtZ//o8Y2MuyREgiogBTlzh0ymtNyhgNqLZLK4q@yAhmYPDfkFcTyRiUlFiQcDrHLHJeUzEn53anqJTJJ/1SSEhdS3t/e1h0Fgf@yPRjJIaUBdHHsmp4cTIh0XaMSyh3bfZhsQh0uHQYIgNq0s5nbftm7UkI6OWNQYzqkA/8WBG30MfY35hhRHihVVV/nsjG6558Cl1UIWkUQYIlAKhZe/0M90QNe83Ef7n@9CJ6LmM5nQnKEHUBCJQ@hCUyfiSg5MgoRkPz9LCxjOr9xo7YGHFJngwEL7jC6MuD33XupIHFNWloZfmqWv2jcw/oU9u0Za4MJJCwwRlO0/ffZ4/@nuk@3PTjwtn1@w5zLlAiAO0muDLCQPON6wtW7wponFQnAxaBsONi/gAhNQUIJh94nrAOOWMYjMM7CCavjMVOKr9sCKu8nrhTlHX@kLq8NJ6Ak2Ph7UjwiKdneIyojDp/ewP0f6GXje2K0oCrTywaQtg9KqfNGxh3pfoXjQMQyHioqqy/4Bjmu4y2JAZtyZwWPwwS0QHWY0gqgPRzYoLzRJiKyBJTh4GrUamv0B6MI4k2g4STmkYCqN0gUNAXRlJSwbMWCyAW79b1BPIiftr6haidO1mtFyihgEW2j@EHatZ4DqlIDeClCRvGZlJ/dO7rEZcGmEdB1IjMkbNMjhMuwLhgwESRo1RT0/QA5xCxwvRV5BOHo9wdFc4FJKPpMrqoW8AmoZqGkgs0o45iaNdK8zkDxbAniS3aNxgwgV9tyObvXkDd8QZBbkvo@gqNnGy5MTqwkC@sk9yhtO4DVmzYbaTFbZzSgbfvhkFah3oXhIu4ED0C4ZgTTpy1bws65@k511dWpdXaZ4o7Hf50hj9mQbBKk3NvDrrhFtexhBiXoqGwthFQz8VlkyIDTEqAK@EFMKNCjoaYH0FMyXBEIviodAOcC3IhHYfDSDl4NPiEf4CCrdSPemHXdpxB/lGhwtdceARBps7iCXdnF80IPeMaR85NJQucik2bkRx3F03eWjlRDJnywN4oOuFkKgUflwRNoKp4GBCCgWqefAOYCucNh0MB9lRKUfKA0SpDzh4ANIEBbNHvSBz0BkXpBtXhCeErksFunUss8thNY2WElqmx4f7LcnDk4amt1o2SB4VuNhABoVLsLXaXaxbXT4KCuPTKUAJVBnI2Nk41ACSFfECgwqgs5nJlEXdHHEGppVRsLpF4Avsfs7wMU6Bh8vkkaoRAFJ7bK45yjb0ueKLr0Bar5FtsLCb0en1qnSjwMELM4T0yiJPwJK0ok9okAvaLwFPR8E4q4wnnkDKDFQmKjX7LFhXdf5uEaYSFZpPjceB4ZvWomL@NraWrwSr8fTYNoC0yaattCUAtMWmSQyYTgZTRQjTSb0bVAMdGvGrxoB5GmyiTQwRcnhjTlO6I1KJdtM6w3V/2r4TUJVAOYhtIQfgBNP1mpoTCbF@jnO2YD8Hin7DtLOUccxxz4KvgoCAbf7OMgSEkC9R2neMaqom96OkVHNAaXRQBEz4cRPGpmT5snFSTd1chVPY@xkVa@BfgjMy0uM5L5jT8YguDVyFQl4W7KRrTSr7Vo8E99IJErSEBLSk8mPSsmUznGdiBtAU4mTkzig1MdOozNwCN40rSWTIaIgHz0TtIzhMBGXL0qQfjvZTKbiEDcZTwNbrsXjgJcOIsGlQuOIACeiPXMKqISGCV1cdE6BGCRNTmFz/dwYD2ZONEA46gZSNo6gzyf9cW0EcvEol3zD40cFugVNP5B7eTgQbnHwDuWl8Yxzd4Hn9ERZWLIS9LtnUm9ke7ryqQxKkxzpLuNrcUWSoCckHw6Jiv3EdLEJ65ZhT9zoSOPSAVBMHVyPBxNglsF6njRQlTkWjM7AZvH1@wCdhfM92JXg1JXEJ8ACAN2ODD9koiiV4GQJSBe0MsMEvkhrWmhURqVMcNYTjM3nC@PXcphaleKwDCZk9i3bMSRACcQQaBkKLWIS6sxfCbNPI1835iV8X@rSUPE2DeCIe0NbJ9xydh2ZDxqPIvFBP4coh0ZXGAL/6AF7lHldOEZX2RBoltZ2BtBDQGmQE2thbY18D8V2x13Zm0JUIYEdbtSTa3cgdJ6zrqZphU6@Vwn8kCoA2QOoJNRKLVBxAy9JBc@kX8m7fFgo0NGfHjzc5WMn1Nli94rjaK2R3Z2AXOnrTYeG1U@zXaAn07JHJqAhiP/mdHho2x7X8sGyamSGK83maDLUaczn@rDMrfE6dtse0lDQbVHn4SeOqw91PggV@G5/@gRk/efHRzW5Egmk6GejW9PGccjlyXJ87kfnHGm@NZgecjlhiut5EfutYJkcshnfo4AeE3@RHNRR4F5E96BJ4RyK715C9xEukANZ2R9FIGvo6AcsU0BcNIcrh3zHCzVzhe4rdbAwnErhuOA4z@2FqpH7mdfrLThnyflUQtY0nDvnyJkvnlvQEaNZyvNAuJJuIUwUUIHChAvqrofzmVe41mBgDIMZxEMQTHCWDPr2IYpPoJugJM7XvBkgSI9xMoQ4NE6xsQ7Imu6NYQtoU2OJhxZia9ROoA9TUHIR1hXmD3FXqaVYtj816XLuaYNqT6Mnm3U@mY2qk8O1NoUPvq@3AMRmvRosUFoVDFOKx8NgBJXyBjGomDR/f6Oo4WoMl8bUBYpSFVwFtIaplpFOpsXd5mVccQkNPSaenEw/ymifgfqBq8vW7yl9o4oJrsJXNfCJ@6Jqe8YkEOwwFB@f7gyAnbDUdBGVUD8Tq2cPuxKfDAO6YFyNwgry1yKEq978xY2G6QQL3mjFIY@KbDSyVu4G3GtVWr8ZILK6LgQEreSCXZ6mzy5ZA3q2M9kdD02vya5kz24NECXexLGur8Pjoqbj6DNX8Jey1Nj24cefNjJNDkEY6TjBVeK1OA2Wc4J8DPIQrq8FEy7I8UyPOnxacGBieVUZMjWluRDIPsDgCVRZmJBfIsz6pXE5L0vPAIU0YWDO3dkozYzkldwb6p5nWJzm@CzjanTz6SA/mRolv@XPLVRYhiZgQAA10Q@yWGVHxw93Dw9loFw3Ed/FiZoKNEe9MwA5ZFWhA0xGC19hH3Xj7COMk0TtXICmBkpGy48PRF0Fogc1A1JHFtE3nAQ4JnGOpQPONK1FEbkg5iMIl1V1PMJRCCxhJKFMBKyyNP/PLa5R@fmsAMWnCJOA7sS9CuDWTMoTy3wtu9CfkHgKQeJcJ4VuobaeIKa2riaJehxzhDPEoEiRbAglaDSY9AaYHgQWWbNZ5VP9EBb1LKeP2BVFqgpa9VtTg6qvgTNILgTBj157y142MlK5mVpfBorWkPkLdnn5I3ARwiJo11ia7HqC2vuNhszzwKf8OCN/TlrztVXpFbbODSIfWqbgwbooYjq0jGpxOdTiYitoZMhKaMQFCxKwhJi/nNqnWfInzg@qDUYjh0SSXYRI1xDl7PKScMjWNUY4BJPKeGVcBUomMKbHNpTmsb@UOioEUGv114tgmz0RxECbWpyQRR8uqStn14RQ6UyMxuNCoGmd2jStE5paGVnNo@AXxh6dDm/G7JnugF4LQcM88LDaqty5o3aPXksC0OyGP29ODjRu7ou8ICvqyiF9aAh9ScqLa0UWkm0bvYnVp0lGNDPp9R0hpXKJAvfabXNVUEACLv8KvkuCAZNCetbknKwGa7NxxAX6I2BcXEmZF/36MiO2gHfoHTyI5X//6ze6gP@btTOAjgIHGENDC7purCmpt7Ky/KhoodfyiuXj4JOhqRNiyHQXyI7uQJH0YWhYDprm2iUJuv8Rzhz4NQ60iS8QDm8hM55zPvEXfJcnsmzuzAKW2VkV9tqyK54UzfKA/tYlJHAhyDQoErEuXgnGlM@0RDRpZGN3ZypYG8WImHm9DybehL9BPr2zEs0x/m5rm37ITF5vqwZoiHrbNG6pckc/nXRtaXzaD@XUwpKw89LTVK8E4oA/69tC4/Li8wI6Zh/62eC7Kti8a1PO6XMXVbjWxB1LbVK2u9xGDWF0SwrOkL9XBTH9TU2hYTXWzCG93pMSfehAKP6iBwWXlEoRpJnX0DzU2zOUQQYfTmXhAgLgOLVOKpXJrphBHo9Xx0eFkeKXy8tjT@UOx8eyoQCFL1uV@GAZFdhfyHpHrUJ3ZY70oaR1I8aVzHzZ@oMbQcOpS4pjnOHEzdnSmptjHzukzmSoO3PTLSQ@z0cwW7Bq4NnvNp6ZHRvEgTFTi7KqBV1HpMMglhmsgJsnhKuG6RVZ5WAuQ2MX1ELsxKXQtJwF2B0PV4auoKn3YGh8RSaue40QiWyvwlTHPsffSvFhAKopfy/v0d4szdV7MCdp2Bnq0I@v7A4WxgBxjPEOQj03XYNeyxF7ujSjXme41H2xCQSje9HRurvI2jWHtsuO6H0bgvoOYIG/lxN0FJembkk05h0138KDgqUM8wrVh317WCj1FR1eK2t94vSQ7/vf9@VwIYdS1Ts4VCD@2Jbqf1fy9VPFOb2rgmiDl4PLWCPGW7rYZWzKn2JZXTpQDHB@bnnJ9jIliikrfERvRcI4s3Kuz4Lv36HrWIXaoOsYz0icBukOI5RLYPAcLmL/XVLL3Z5a9/2Y0g2wxbsKEanc06EBnRW9b1Qp0zLqB8ZQM5n3Z1G94cSYGEsVjYP2FwZuN75FyXj/TGX8Yqz7A/I4B4A7UMJQb3zN8L1yjf002m5lJvrQ7Bh3izKLTG0M0vcYVednYHiGhpsx@tZkvFCrC9qZdXg7ygbjoEnb3YXcoc@H8qHSHZLSgnzuGvS7VWPiGh6uA6vlMpmML8BEJlYWLLdpUtkw7hcmfy8kTC7zlOdhcTLNiRiXp0Foia40XMmCtFWKPQUulxXLtAxvhu/35KZt2x5@SE0BU@2aKIqBZEkram@rsRvijr9XhM2HLlwc8Gj3Vg1a8N7G1y0BP6g031bp0Zmf96pNCec2RzjvtGi9ffgmMo90Vyq4TxvHhPga2@FqWdIfDVHlkly8tdVxCdVuG0Odf6aF3G3wynL2VniLTMOfk8U5XD5zO59xj11jSuMZIMvsgpYyMEYGWW@R8vUuHingf1YGmtr4W@U9NYyOMt01OqsCjE3gCxa@F6aKI8KSZ1ugX3m4nA/1lCEuGPVdV3HgYHJvKZL3R3rf4GdZ3MYp5wMWuGiGq3Vz4/KhiwpfKNOBaPPDC1aTBDSqU2PmBt@lAJ/MOlCvk9Hdw23XGn8Hx0Dfo7WvWql6s4u1BvbAGhgDvjw8tK1qHECPHj975LasQ677A1yxNh4vrGSP4nNoD4fvg09kjZxR2nZvaZ52cY8rbtD6ILgzvQ0e/ufOwTvd47wDDStbzcCYQL/k2p49NiSyrQo6xIEe/l7FQ4O56L/rCNKtej5gJPj@XeHfqVv2ddsbj@nTGg8nLr0oqkRbk@@Sm3p8BQqtfbSdvvzGHrVl31H2l6fQFPhyFtM2vc4A94Zzyjb6drszMO/KdNvQPcs8VYIhH259L90VMWMy6SE6y0MT0OvMZKSXWtT/CD/7qyrdHz3i3VpouEVeWTZCR7uvpbF@2nH5aCiaWAUHhCOtke/RrtAu98rrienNgUaWLIXDu3xaAg2r8u4vklgpWdFWiDkb9hdPrKRSEtJRIJeMDAg86qpkF5ezRZpYNstfqzIULSXlKLL85EPQ7S/xodFBMzJuC@4L9LWwNmlpJ2cNJn33JsPkw/VdENHwtXrYgpYsR4asoc/SLf@zCs3aUMG9jPBtgcw1MW6dU8nfOqlC4dShpNsmfFrwgaqbrBxDG5pjl7@Z1Fs5FecvWQJd/Pp8IcfNbLky7VdM1@jxKRA03SUijmwHFxyDDCJ1cCYdR9CRmXPBizMuy@4DU5eGbB44CLtKbFm6Gmh59Yd9pvTZU6Ov45Lqx6aHazKXUAWR7LJVRHfC/tpEd82vTaBkq4gND2bg05BOdAc/2pbAe6L3zc6jhYoIM@kj2F/QyT8L5I9ON@vifGC6uKIpNNwyMIUkx4kYqa4FesOSkNfH7cMzKeYNiO92XBp62di6PZ7hprAZmW4bVjc9GmX1v6tUx1VrvW7NxPlkNJ64/md5HmjNVHQUenRK7u65CcCl18Ba2UAfestHqiNDriCF@Z3i3LhKGv/cHNp99nkpw0BoAyEMhfMlhPMAuudnuCDHsZZQIqX9ntOeONAhObxgr6FujSyTTMv0bh/N8TxcnBN8sTC858CNCMpjfMv3PxSCdLwcI4/vlvXnO5Dv6N@B8o7sidMx0BgeKxJVC/xUjZ1gkTFu3LDxWJTzqJbWsYfQvMAwXNpkOrY18SRnYt3aKxRu7RUqbFoqRMiAJb62@@R5MkoNtCj7LinUAOVv4g5nc9PKBQPXiMy0QBBbzUcXQwe6xEN@HNIhrQi@I842ntnUIXb90F6m7zybQQfy3goTMP/J6KHRwWnDO9N@aj@xLRt6ozEwytGhwbf2Lyz0WB4Roz3GzeuAn@6dyRwR2BWdEJc29LHRhvodzk3v0xdxwA91T1/RFdHYIOl/oelOWjGHbcP5ggb9IuZVKu1ihh4ZU9ItVhMMb4OS1@lwkRjH4xbayMKMjTu2bYu/idtm4KM@uZ2rQFdAr/efKJdxvf3CuMBS/WyxqAdnfJWI0eVnT6wqq2O07SF/37ImyTL5mgDdMQ1XeYxHGZBbIcckkL7cW3lI8VYeMleNQJI9012apF@uasxBqtMPWAI00J2OjTNhvuGW1TmR8wfuYNPhEn6@cKANiJ8Cx9I7E/9wxbuyNRy1R/RaqTBEavPQaOPmnzYd2uHp05uVyUeG/BMLIiu6wn3@AbvCRl1giWegjSTv7rYW9KhFrJpjehGnXjldTot1JMs0Om90HDWzCV/zsekFfyiz8pSMK8aqI82IRpEVnTa0L21Ji0vXQKAZGpI3cEDnV7zbhreD01SWzIdMRgZOMi/OwqwUXW13QIW1l8@nh8zVMST/SD/gJeHxflw@lLZXSp4IHv4PHnxVgU64VcgFJ4wA67p7Bh8yP3Es//M@FPjMdr2eOT2AfOMugFXsBIuVhyjw4S0DTRurCgG1Z02GfPShH1l3NeqSOibRqbWSNCR27RmSYZ1JdN7b9GaJbL63S9nG0049oyv5xx3gTIP0ONjmFQbzv0smUKO8ERd7qgpH7LSQ85d/LkPuecAZQN6yPWns0lcZu8/2Hx8cy2NXXdo/bQ9wd8QNOW7h/AStlIkMSX2hO5H5Tr4crWu6nvLgSJV2Hu/LGGAFvvmMhgQfnJlb@Kwc9/SPE9UVfaUWhL6Gt1xAfHT85HFqvhOTJXYGjj0yklHvnaOjNO40@erRUu9o7D1oHT17ujL6/q6qJpeQ73OLZgdXcc8lKa2CdGyANgrE@Igfv3KncNWxx0b3eDY2PoXOEzm4@57JF1YW8ql@ZvaxFbLySkRRQ2VluZBLRlZmg7JtOOF3VX2emmPklh36KPyzcjkKSg5Zxckulx5um/G/LsWwjL8S4cMiqZmb1OqZErSM/gBNiu7@fTOmquoqPB/pPahXll9ZWYsBls0PD@2z95hKNnzlRQqdJA@oSjLvXEdelEbAuhV84fC87wjG9splMLcBCJ0LSxv8uWHNdEuiuazbxIsKxMZFbbcG@dx4jwmpcIXPGR7wvHSOL1xSzxIdMibvSPjYiUTZ2Xmwf1eEQx@Xt4f6@Olz9kx38ayR2wNGc2y8R47nktEXEo5b4UF3K6dTuw6A0m6F1x8vb88VdqQ7XduaTe@ehKOtpti10xnCISy0USBjaE7NZX1Vh49rPVu@zOiutPkmDnu2IAdHz6DxAb379r9Q1UyGThjCr5rh1jtqJmjgLIEmfYbH1kW9jvdD1tBBuUUGh@RSbfSxMcXlKHw0eJlSv7R/K9zS9xWTq7uT2/xKt/jlbknvhh86sqycUW8BmL/Fj@Xl0PuxPTwf2PKO7hjukvXHSzN0W0HKtxSkHOHOb0oZHASliUXfvFrEx60L/mcptR4bnpMbD@y2mVtahu0eniXJnuCZ6Df9/eUUukPLW/q2v@WD25endz4xlib0RH@z3IM4zelSL2CCxmBCWyJuei9OkLZB5jWsvsmPUWQPbG@XbEsz@czGFetLk3xojh9OxqszCiwRT@@/zsUXAr4AVdk@d9kD3BE3l86XqPy4LG65@ypRloXjgXiI6KPj7YCoDo4ULZLiPBefPVtwxj2j3sFRxM0xptNVuq60xIfv2TucWNFjnd20fzAH3@PKdxa6cnD2diJhpVLJ5OKNEdFtknj4aWIdD/9bpy2REPbykq352xDBQww2NvobL/GMMFCLDNw5KRAIr7YOydRqar7MtvCahgoIPUlKEZ3oJKYgrQZbv/D3FFYq6hVbqzGxIjJ/V2d4sCo/HBTg4rGGUCYmnaps3QOf9WBHIqNz7tklI0UKJDc1nwGbrET3Zlf9PZuQpfWLZ/vPdo@Ot4@fHzUyzSt/T2dQCMuC1IKd4x9luyKU3UcbMGh@VDDtJR5CcnQGPypgblAuBiW7VrTaQtHmhRK3MM76hWUpCm1rVaQryJ8k8tTIF6QtdOKwgxJT/fg7mit8hyltlIUq4qBFShPqrMIyyxIe68Bs1i3f//p9IuSL981U8MYZTNg/3RWaWt@2u36KrsHufoIU97b3Hz8/3GVBBudEc252vUGtnOeH//Kt9lBPPZPW@dRY3I8Sh7qq1eJ7cUBMXI6zCm1EpoN3gc4hWIAd3MLsx95giXWCDxiMh5Wi/NdvKFdxGZesJiFsPMhUHJIFkidCWVtbY8dAJOzh4f6nu4cM87/7kJwRRQiCHeMuyD/9cZcfXR8cRhLcteOMiEXQoQ9CdCd0sD14voMZcU5Nd7z6xh06Kp72CYdn1IeXbAgCXWEAdHtO54hdO2MqSce@8BuC/CPAgoSIhILjrnF0FI/zclx2Zrom7lLGPPTwdK1FYscFFXSinMy28TohvLRIp3sUIOsTy@Mn2PjnXcSA0uSQ5aTZOmWW37ogRgLGN9eA2NsGdBrMtUDlNLwK@wIoEUcgK3wXuyTV4zeiBKArZJIG3mgYCXjjOC5XOXGUd7/yz5R@lYHZA/N3fPM08wBsv@TbemD@ZW5@qSCh3Ty@a56XaIbwyD2/BDwjIf4R95FblCx@csAccXjKWMBXmTmCajojrGNwngJ/S8CO53ASjU@h0oDcoMb8EwN4eobTTOCZfxVFQZJCQUam9drGlC@eunb2XyFfyKkKZFI6CwDSYd193BXKASaTFWgmwpk5rr2CXnJzc5OJqM0YtUKV16yybr3Miq/CjK5DWOF8gJlrMIgDUeYxwK/uR4POJ6UmMSpyr7gaR8bVtaFXIn/svdBu@YgQWQKQxXFk4OnPU7xwy3NmwRmWbbyiKnKRw7oPSFKhTyJTUhT8vfZPbQ/IBxrp/KoWvtceFw/yHhAPh3P5dXN0dCTSo3yzZc23iAY3RvhtTUYewEFlM9c702jdii8QxBGCqIjLyLfxkp14J1ZT4bTJgEx/uISYLTD/otJfQbO83Ns3Dw5MXD/2D5HF7h9ZNqpte1AYltAULauoheS8SLnc0iL5JfKTgeLgsSWXkBywKWAZHcP8wh672zu7@189eHZ043A8Chm/Hgz4fn0zdSLJ6UYzNMSjxVqskgd7ytGTB3tBRcwzXYhwY2D8fknU20oyH41BkPPV/deLtiyH10u3Oscv@P7f6/nNardljSLdyIea@YB0aYWttEf7ZK4nrpWWYSufvy1Lc3hKBPQO3@R4I6uJ5MVVo7lZP7Fi8ZuUsKQhvIzJG9gIwHTibqwrSOw3C4cFCy@CPMYbo9xoW8wub4viehbPaMI91p59Oj@dyneIeETKGyQDLFKQlSDoytZ3wGX0@RlqGr@okp/mFD2rJpLhQuY2jEdAHQd3XiIXmZ8A6R9@ONDdwdBsC8EZQfwQxOCstvD8Q36@TyIp@PcI8IQT/i2Y08pUpuU0iSRyO4KVZredpxjASwrQoFG6ezYBxeyZPebnStO06UMjMB3awH5BGyR9y2BfnYwgXI8@hwYNYQPnliAyYDIeZpXLUsAl/OMUpyk8sBLSa@Chin7B5VE3n5gm5YEx7Zp94O2JZBo42keq2mThkYtYaDpi0YqLVGfzWri1KX6MW1ejaP@gczen8wzoDV0GLdKYJuLn8WSlCemje/z8xVk8KS6jJTr/0z8Qs3v9INAw@0X1dk6ie37rDE7ZXMYtyuWbXALcrgPmJ1UFl9qUy/LAFeiSshpK7kee8xiMIEYkeiN9zBITi5/yJTOyJk4SVpqOP5Lq/KBAi6VSpFDBhzxkRjF7ZOL9d0K3Ziyh1IAI0NW1uvh5Y45ZQ5XlJpgpkSRbx8umdkDiwuPtkgLowBClQmBrSEKgZkCOeCOROYFDHPSHsPChs9KWeNPdOzTSZyNOqNSsfo9FLg9blBzFcrniV@giVywzoL6b7FBWAOwNPhfI9YBd/wAQwBmov7IQmzPymxwvRunGeEYe@SeHQHZikcM9gwNFGMCaH73ZGTj4S@xa0FZAPqhUnh/vtUpJRWThCSR9x@ziSDQ/nzpU8fwbRaCZKgtB41Wu0X2M0fCstxY/4gSPHNujBiNeY6mxKBqu3@07p01VvZXq/Yh@LUDIHHYA/k6tVgAODzUM1gQs8VvO7H/2M7w9WEysq@ppyzlLxfOZKrzUap7l2UfrJ5K03sjU7q/roEV5r6cnoJMrG7mHZ8ag197vKyeiyLIspygb8b2NZ6ZWePl6epVVS69Px2qhIb@eNsVSLX3aZM@effa29TYpTs9mr8WTBJ03xXYOLkU1h2p@rFJmF1uFbOy0jNdE0h88b0hTP2Vv4DntMfwn85tuxKyjud3DsGJcZLGTE7wVWCyKitKIN@GfgLyChyv@jbpcl7eab98mG7ruTWc50zTHbrcLP3sAEqSWPNLuVe4RqrPZ/D2FndzDw07vAetnTX5NdIw/qVRCYr6D1OBu1dG0R27TbaPfn@zqM@5uxib42fP8uE8@f/HiBRpe0MPeHMZ82BxikEalpedjTMtof/qTtav0xbPW5p9@c6QYa/g5wM93rp6g@UjNf7S29tGDB7lcWtM0bn72@bOvb29v5x6m888a@a2clFnb/JM/XlvTtE1NWWu6rtqMN05PPxO1TE6U//RH8dazZ19z3Xr2//jG27qKryK8zlgR@AQ8WaaCEd8l@KkoYzHSK@9@Ym9iQOVqbEZ/rVjoscbU@lbxv33v4HXMi9U15YUDXy/2OlYoxbgRDGDLBrazWD22icEKV7GZUqvVwFj8b/8e4te/CnDQZ7YJr3o@gFWYxepSjaJcxuoFMKiaBun@X9/4RiSHnE3USIwLnvusAY@YK2riVhOeDXo2BTzZTcooinWvb0M/BvqcN/AMWy3dU@@h2TRs/FgGnoRteCcxvHaVHdxn7LCRSqWackuCR35JuruqaifAANgCadHYC2HJt3IXFnUL6cR3Ab8XMaIpICqiK272HYjUuMOL6@FeLHmqL/6xn0MhVli7/@phvQ6sMFvPbtRT9LCToAIUViyJtn1fZGn2Kg6qSqP56jHjB3PWxUxJE9Pp9P0WWqeIUmkamyOQcRyx2AJmY2xuY1GnGAuisXmYDw23i8@f/a9/9v0/@x79fZ9@/wmPyLO6Zk/ZgHhn0HTq8NyvVDr1ulh3xIsTtNeB3jKVUqWktK5OEhvAqZqHTM18fBnPZ@NHjJoc0MlJMhgPjYVPvY4v@vdtZKLvNTffpx5aKMQ8yt3hKF3ogv3FhFLjrN6UUHCqSQ21kG9KnB6pjPiUWeM@VJOoFctis67ltQOoOlXkFTdYd5kdAw2yAJG24FmDP/qHJ7Su4ZjzGrmtBT4U6uazFqZ75wMwK@qGllXyHxV2NSHWaChNowmCLHSvfpD7a5W1UqVQ0ZTWLXBZ9aaTYRjP3NiZqnba7fabTluHp613dNW7Lxflkqxt6hN9qs90rz1pT9teZ9JRVSH2trHGDnkzaLJU8Jyk7nyey3LLN5LBxp8k2dOYEPtHeOqqprINYKQZeIH0QEZQ7vAPysFiF/A032403m4AhdRTm9Q8m3XJzyV85Nb9Zkq6umqAuVr1/zfrobFKDzdB4ZpXqdTmy7okNV7WGykA@dIHKXOYcqve3CSPMC0/Md97s8kgvdRmY7Nm79APosAjNQHg5kIm799PyWC6DzHr602WTKXWJWkNeXfD51EQtllPBYXBtBMsnrPjBfs@KBVQ/1ebV/WrxubV1eYm/G/S@8r/guvV5o1/@syfFWHm/k3WyGolkG/q9ZOGUj9RTnzaa4JdVuroIisnYKjDF8JBXybEoHUaFSG2wTZieIJWNrYhxF69@/J/xt/Juy9/Dzt6Bn9CTNlA/aDM1QR4MfbEYk/4Y1nwD7/Aii7o8KSOjhZ/WTiFoCivZFbho7QJtVRIysgKW3avhbtxZfYKgjLkD0zUSgWxlVJnGottioUicYifv/HE4/F/8korF@NcncYtpK9c130Sydk8bxC4qmVUSb2s81OS@bn1P7/s@Sc/v@oRYpdlwBoDpucyjg0hBlUQk6S6EKtvjnCJIY5nS6g6nNU@k55vS6jr6h7NVnS4Hlfb362Vy3U@FL/@jEhn4@EGvFX4312DUgjYswixC3y1X@Pf4zf4x447@Hf4Gv/Y8Rv8O/Twjz1p49/xa/zbbuPf8Qj/HrzGvyce/j3v49/Jz2WzalVcvyBUpNSyerU@FQkl1dhW/eTneCX14j/97je/Ga/V4lKcjs7PqaD2q8kqINN149X7cSFWY@vqupoZZjoZta22wWCyjMMyg8xA7UI31VJZxmCZWWbGMiNb7YLJgL8MmMxMj2X6LGNlLAgIvmDyWhkPTT349OGvB4Ac@DNxAUxbzXQYJDRECZLu3ELwYLpsnQgNUIXFVwaI97IqZ@SC2cSbChriq1cnykZTK5eYjBQitxqvTuJNPNNWK@dYe2asnbxiMRf0g2pMOTlR@EgHlJXQcXXVau0@fdhqKcg8T57YB/P/g4NR1Hrr/@jAfnJgj2z4Pzg4eAJNr566nwL2cv9@DdiN/9mK1atbJxXiVgHHiimbWyf1rITmQgp4kYZuqQ985hDhW187EeLnCRTtzlG6q744r55VyXweWMHQqs4DBMG4wf/Ccw6MOZDizuE5O0cD2dB4/uIkNHGD8uL8BNUcUKrCf0VZsP4D/Jv/7/p/8pwlWaLRTCYurjYT9CTxL5m8uLq48t/1ZCLhWxKb8IcOYMcoF1d1NFKgCzA1Eslm8uqKu8E7kdzkAOuQzGad4s7DAQ@JhUlSsvyV@If9QtL@cxKvMn2@RuHkZJrJJKvt4ChunHHTL2kiOFml65bW2w21@Sc/ouPWt5IUKJ@rVtUNxi1aTqtWc4GtWKpWS4FlPZEo33zqmS21AMJaLpdMVqtg2QrAZsAagi0B2MCSB6iGq3d8Lnixf0AHkQOXyMfwBgDOFhIZusYAb8SJixXx3r2Ef9Pu1nby3j2tnLm8DF3GY3BSF5xara7ptFronr28FFsiLRko58GeKV1eqplySo0nbSfxFK9SgqQSkso@0uqUahmYr5YrJtk/yAPA8pubhVy9XsiBuVDCycubD2GDievx2EXQcxeTnDXG1xWxyvVQaN0uPuziKkbVznL5ZAKYaxKEv6sY/nFntVzm7kmWKyRKqbL/V1tLsjqIIvwPle1sKrdR3LgPohr@TZc@yJOrF0ZNvapdGBUctLyqdvyLLHEDsHHvXrYMaC1lqidCq/Vw@3i71aqJooi9KrzQkbi7gPdnjZ14g6o8X242sITNk3i8Ur1P5KGW8gzowA8nxaGbYKUyIUIwe7i7H0ovqP5Qxpqg0RdfQtkf4ADHGHbr/NeFh3VZm/XxYX1mmiYz2ZAeNmTcn96dThjI5o/vG1opLj6hixE@QuzZ4@2d3eO0timxmLa3vZPWjp4/iKlozc/t5J1F@@Hu9sOD5xDh2ePd7aPdj/c/3X3@DNxddj5/Aj7vv@ffqGmJ/Zy9EL5w3uiGoRsTw2idTybnr9kXptkyof6GEyiE3XeYa7Qg72N9Xo4q/Dqmq3/xhe6M6WHvfvjtdz/879799nff/fa33/3293/65fe/Db8fw@@7/Pvdf1fO4/unX/6L33n3W78Njv8Jfn8Iv5/89Mtf/wb/kf2P4PdfIm5/5P8i4fhPAFi/9NMvv/ejn375yz@A37/yfz@4@fuVnyz/ff9bq38Y73u/c3uY7/57@P0uhxWE/e5vcTf83gj/WzzcL//g3a/9B/7/J/4fGn/73a/9Eb58yz//wZ/8l3ff/I@aVvqTf/vuW997961vvvvWd959659q737936qZ6Ot33n3/9//yD373L//gf6T/H9P7d9/n/90P/vmf/y9//r/9@R/4v5/A7z@A6Sd//h@hbfzN7/8Q/7/3@3/zhz/E///pX//N7//q3/zSvyHDb3DD//2v/h1//9Wv/Oe//s3v/OVPvvHXv/qTv/6N3//L//2X/89f/89/9d//3l/9s2@i42/85C//8Jf@4pvf/otv/cu/@OaXK97fvvX95Xu4f/mP4PL@@XwfOO9Trg91@fLvlJ@/DzbmqQCdAHX/4rtf/wUg8F9j7N23f4yr5eG34v/Hmkphfsxt/x8waDfLjD4ZMMHvV999@7uIov8BUAT/Ib6@E1oWfLjlO3MLoPU3l0T6xZ9@@S9/RLaYUanTODh21yWtlNoAlWajXPa7bH@IHKL8wiK0EICf0neQQy34fQd527sffuPdj/7pux/@xrsf/hJ2mFKunN5OS@od8wsQMP8e4TBg4X3CYcDPMP0UjQlJqc/Axj7zPT/77DOhdangtoz7l@D6GTnxh3Ev3LbhewV@6I77ONgli5p9Y8Y3rvuuYcqUC0w1RYLGRiAF5bNsmvIzNMVRS/yCOwSabpBxim9yRe@pgK/5/9w4FVgKw/AHr48KjGTw4/lJcKOQh2RS02mALhLLGBeFNrgLzbhRurkywxJMp6kp6LtggBRS4PUgxWq1Wgoj1nh@wMqzVi8xykoqVYNyY2weJ90qIYjpA4ICMWupQ9baqE15xBTCqwfoSAnodCiqmpgq1R5CgrXpQ4awEDiBffWqVi/VpnUE95bjIzVNPaA8IbBaalp/C/YawYR4QuzhW8hKqZZK1UuYIBaSV0@6xSspT4WjsqdYyq8D@OIg9tZ9xj4S1ZLY4tIhIoyHxndqHhoDQnDwP0lt@MWh/8BIvw1C@Bol5afCuP8WCaJbXDbFAABXkmRZZvDDObstdh@8pxxUipKFT4pDSBFFEAWEDgyHfVJCiuo3RRZIP1bb@OAHgWFh1tfXhVhdzIoHMqFOUZhzWqFV5LiwChWPChMLZRGdDVpSH@QF4lcp/fU4Tj3EGQfMPkrx3/37G@wjKCZ9524Ck1JZO2fHOJTNVErUAH7dTgkvQQMRgE4J0KUgT2uk5KSEdJoxuRZDP3ZwcOBnghxe1oQUkLmWVdGOs3GTySQGMWQ5LafT/lemLznIvkEmX/8rryNy6SpSpmm5KihKVYZOLKrVqKAAo@Pbt2@hVmilSmUfdFPmL1rRciXyBAe@K304nAVbL7RcWeB6OVMLOcYSNAwKT5IlBZZgG0mBr2/mmQieRFwrleIUDrAvJzaCNUwFlcgBh0Bjdcxo8HBlsZRPBp47B2zn4MmT3afH42aTCQZdrWq0xo7dMVw3gX7bTx/yte1auZCMNRoI@riiIYMRdisZYn/7Dw/3jyqMF9qvggRlrEozT34xy6oQG49fbMb8NRwiXhtki0f4rszLltDKWYgaqwuxjoEaBU4pohpcZVXhidt/YE9B5U@LYlotoBqXpIFfJnzdnjA81I7vgIc2hSve5c1NwoBQv5BoYB6NUFsFoV73Vz8xVagf7R5DhOMDpmoZWah/xqYyJihdCfVhbWhYfW@wjsuIxJOMGCnTeiOTxj8tm4W3miuk1XyxubY2vJAwzROqtgtcD3YF1gsJi/EVeJjwFYF9BZzggTRwkRfzV9jtH1T9ZU54fEyCr3US1Tw0s6RwAhXNwQnj6FOFHxA46PWRnxBb@/xzj9XroE1L@3tCDBjGgAWLfSSzKw9kqunuxDHIt89Y1/zUxCuh5K7pjof6DFoPICR2dXXVA0j7e0yra2TlMbr4vuqQSxvMV1NdiFmVSu2tmisKOa1SeZvVNAEchA0FVxOtAQ3QZOuGwv@qLiSSzZYUYFaqKMInm80KOCosVPCqeDx3uKaFj4DLraWPph/VahLzl4FkaAkI@YAH63sOywR@Re7n2woC2WJruJxIoHGFbLYcDjj8/8@yh@ZRNsf1bEbdVMZg1MGY21R0MLbBmN9U2mA0wVjeVEwwTupZNbOpTOoCEzb5oXAM95zXRM@Y4hmU3E2su8awJ@POi5pICWjipn/Iat2PV8ctLLbereHGZNxukEheCP3aOW2SE4xaX8b97Y6lD4VurWt36MZZoSu37e5Mdr3ZEDcrDG2nFgcZLh54mHgvMG7LqxkgROAY1VY2m6s0WFMe2@MtQcsXUw01A9wff2opraXXjK1isdKVO0NDd7bylXwp3cV9EP4s0lY@U@nLnz15/MjzxocGbY7YypUhAh4Og8c4bJUq@Xyz0RDFVIOSaeJFmJy3SGtr0BoNvSvBt2dbnitppSZE7ppOrRaPb2VVTVIr2UxJuAoxJABusYB1AWOmsGBpxO@F33Qrlm0Bo6ik9bR5QUio9Hq9q42L1Nwi6BcStwF6riQ93b4IrVUpEq7CJmnJnHuCi94DxF/4s2cVUcuXxGqjOrcXC2K1eSXcHxldU8ctESeZi5uxCsBQOdQYJHTChKuKY9tepW30bMeYB8yqhSAgz9DNADnxKkzuJIMpXtxMroCBAIccc0DM/JS@Oi0DbKjlXHMXWESjuRmc34dEHHv5Utfrdaiwi1xRy@VzeS1bKOSLGrD8cq6QL0HbyBQyeU0DALlyqVy8Ygnol3RdqteyWlbQNEnLSllVUrP4f4dBw//3D6/Bv4ZviJXVhGPcBP8U@hLo/yz2GDfTejY7tvE6hT57YHRWhNgZ6LRgcsexXffvEeaBbp1yr4cmP3ku9Hqk450y7sj0BitCPB@PcP@84fyjQdgdtSGDxCYowAN4OUPbXhagyJ4/W1HKJ@FZr4AMftgrBD/c//jRceR7vLu980gosAcHTx9e@@T9QHn2eHfvOLQWuW8QNR@C@Pru48fXrf4nd/D8sDexHfwJewfPc/NX6IT78YQcPIuBQmcC4r/QStIWjqyvsXwxMKgCruK@BxrjPd@YL8yNGTS@4JsNTTdcVcz3nVaE42AHos6Qg7UN1uHHJKAKS0cY@QKuWiwLwphZ9jkrZljXHg51vCC3twaOAx13Uxko5Q3pfmdM@tx2ht1zs2usCU9w41ZZxctIMRPCIwAymnTovBDo@fFAvC5eXYtTOe3hxGATvDZ6hSN80AmNjtkfQCd2bgcBhLauM1o39GEPxDeij3e7g8fTILcbPsObwYWYIIqPdE@fxkrVeqZSuXdPfeaI5a2s6PaN@u4UqJU9h9ajO7N0KS96srjH5FasbzaqbnMMNVZQTys5e1zXQTpvgCzr9TpV6Bi3cvkK4LZeyuT/6jd//Ld//KusVNb6NXXjJD5B1o5SNsp4jMQ4X9STSe7XyqV8qZzVSulSuZTLq4V8Pq1qaVCZimWQmjNqSS2U8mU1XcqVs0B7ZfDNl4u@oKgEkqGyUQGwVgcvytwk1UEegI7Ap/HYm4SeZDE9tE@YaEAcUUAtzaNdqhtmDXoppmZYtsgAos46LLa3t5PZ2xPFB2jB5Qs7GVHsoiVfymSKD0TRIJ@dEoonos3jlPDIIdHjlkzmwY4oTjgAPK1XFAdo2S3gOJMommjZ2d7bw3R6aNEwPgQ75T7cMgwsRQhmoQVEWwLwOoQGwbZ5OjnK6C5aMEn02eM@O@Anih8H2UGfQx6MA3gUlHR7WxT3uWV7G312qNh5ntFP0LJNjyg6YIFmIIp9MPQdaICi2AYjNgZR7ICpM9PBDS8lxQNdLU8XxRlHDyJIFKcUWu@cimIrcMdkPvVzk0fsVsii8lLfJ0sZ/0RRCzKNwbKhJSuKudCSg7I9evSpPvC6Rp8/M4d/O1DSR4@yujmd7O61P/643e@3ndn27seH6LWz8wgEhdnEaffbfsR2Cx4bYu080vTT0ez6A6Xeb7Uq@nCp1yetVk63rnm1Zi0DcwixXkPO/KePCY1aO@C186h1X182pUoAW8gHRvBt4/NgBN8Hept7BQ950XfabotVJH@Uu@mqcGiJdGt3eqR3HLuK9mltjbF4Ip6eNQqZZpU82Agk7Ez1iu4IT@Bbx3GR5MWsMa1lmrVprajx5Ti9hHgy1fKmmF4bbanlfGVN31K1XGpawT3ydi/O4pK6xRLqvY03LPE0uaWBiC2ebG1JYkNtbmlqqVIovtyYiGKygu@tbLECATNx4CX4SjaKza1iPhKlWEzpilYpFpPVK8CHBx17G8crWonEuaGfJpOYXdSeoQj8hvIZldOs9hLT9LTG88Vmyeq0plb5GYYscwNWFw/MnXQ82@EQ@wBuupWp0B3oolouiZC@oiSSSdRpSWlVhPnSvxdfOz49Pv5MQIZY97X6Z/x@36pv/fjRjgyKvm/Dg27lPdRvbEfeQXa14MPPYQ2cjkHClx9BTwrKTuCGO5EceyjvTjvGGJWkwCM4vlD2D52Tjx8twDka2Oc8ZdzIXaWTi6yOwfAcYLPL9FodTHqXJShXTE@eUx/eqtdrrdqI9jpDEYNYnzA6JHcOZt/leQ@3l1P0C9yd43u0apmrars2jU0BTqvGJPXVyO6@0lKdaheP/31Qe4CRqy34tqtGzcAL6MWYWO1tWTXGJpar94xnhoMHJ@wfrINEgVt2Ej1mJNfZCV1Xv4N6wJVUd5g1z9nTySgBsnk7uegUsSJqEl8LinxBe8hwmcJVtVdjiZfJ6muwOuss0ZUfJLdy1W7iAWslwSXzqveqxzRWyFXpXs4EQoJGRLjBMuvJWv0TEII44NNKBTLi1/EpwMSUAKzZJQ89OTavqp3akCUkNmVJQk@u2q81MPYlvjYlUWxKUuOyKdQl6YVQh3ZancX0mjtp05nxLNNWtUyhOgU3tZirDqBi9ZfTqlMbTxyjOgSrP8TFt8rpVUAnYA3AvLlMvPuFbyQ3pXyNu1UJ1OUQ5I6W3KpNqxaeQgUkUcvWwCPVyGXSoBrDq5iGbl4rpNVCOpvOpaUiukIfn86nwRFUHJAtEsOEyJiYzkwzsppWDTWdyLwyu6@S6dMEyC6EMpZMe/YuXmgPLlBJSJVkha/OkiltY8igFmymb0pEpsApqlgwwPmAjc30AEEdGvqQYiSTEstuJIbrCQyzfjwZ7zaalcrudPw18EpIr7cKqWIm9SaZrCbWkjXXeC3Uq0IduQqVerwGNOuP/jF3MmpAHYNJLWqVRqONRSxm0tlMFkpnti77m2JdbKYzawUVquiKkXjEOMeIjoahkDN3G7dQ9B4aUHVqWasKMo1aZUuaVFbyG/kMHx7jMYWxz9YQkyxxIgbbQhPxeFGLx5PxKo7Nr4n@YCzwMuJjcWCq8Xvqlgjyl1gRyxoGmLNE2vmXCXIHEtiVgMMKLFcWYhfC1cXVJujFCq1gBOmRrZFJkuv3hViFMRADT/yDaJQ1xj50YWRqs/6Sf09wQTfAFei4SBBDacGSYaIuxj7FTc5bLA4Z051RQ9OyzYZWhI4MmGMQFDTyKk5HxHDFuFwHDLsXkL/NVB3P5viEzWZ6KtwidY@xfmpdoDLHrk85bte2@4fbwXKs7R0cbz0BYVusxsXYRTwWv4I/IXafNiVpfFMSi0W2JfEh95@L34/F43Ec2wZEvY0Rj2A7F8H4VgVvL0roFc4RGs3k26fm8KKUlfgIBbCoq6vYukI1E2zy@OSVBkQRs@zAAZQiHAmCziqfx3HjmPJq7H6ulbJP9g@sh86ewfiej1KuJdZjLKNKuIeiWvFd82Jr7VQFmsiK2dN0jN2P0cJvsVzSRI07VGPsVIqrFb5PZHxUfll8WXr55PnB84M9IXaydrlm4xQBC5evvbW@@jUIGM/m4oyd1GLTWq7qL16r1yV1U8Ozn4qsAuy@pxakzGWdk3WdPAoa@Lz7hR/kppslsGsZFeyalk9p9bq6obFkbPzuy9/DYzwudj/dfsziOKr8t3/8I634t3/8r2lBWPyKRpq1bDEGIdGoFoqxi4vxxcUVPNwvH2vGeKZyxSSY@cSHGqsrqpa1LKvKKoqubxRTOe2@VVX8sGpRTcZcKeZP4RTzMffS99IyJfAK5ljISSxglcR2D828pt7fRGpRwy1sLPzbNNxyTIiVnry6ZAwsnXq33zc1MikKq7yV2OZbaZO9xWmNt9Iae1Wr47S4Cp7hmP8GbvDBqa94PaVsxBloP6zeuKo2U4zmDUBjfGkYG9bJNVo/WWPl8jWnDQv@jA2X/jBS4OCCNbAZG1@4YmIjqSjdrn9E1KbB8nUghQ0FcrYRDPvzP0k6Sb77hV/XtMLf/vGvXLYuW59poC2WywVVi/3sZ5sTa@Ia3frPIOIthzIEGh9Nm@DpCWgINUUm@hfU81ihQe6AkjqxUDTm4QO9ETVFFCzMvgV6P9qEMxSGqPZa/FywboKCbeCe7TSJ1nQOT7IqCKEISqKz0@@kCQbbwNtJoDkLF8JX0At6XFYDTit8ZQ4KHEbQx9qdljucOGPag5GgeGozze5BFEjhK3jk2hrtNffZtQQsTtm4GZVn2SWskeDERobr4gFu0NMIX4Eo/kmSeOm6jsciYEjTgv5BxiCUT/LoNiDtJqQ95BFa5Jqg0vMAacZzxyNZIF4LXwGJgbBggiDBzE0IUAVe9BVAAJQh4QM2m2yTZZPswkylqvPT4a5wATqe0KcHW7IFjIbQungEQBC5iuHACcR6vLsM6cKvYZDhIo4BEA6DT2LXQDHA6GRDyYzOTHhvUACLzidKUNHYvXvzXNVqZjfJqEQI/9Qc4@gW1YO1PK8ALFCqPupWxDTDc/eqgWtIdoDxFGUXqE7iB@5VI1GZiNYrQYD/9yZapMhrVUUeVSyAX1@8VXQAZRAZ0c7rsMM2a0zVikkWZr4Dee9Qpuist1BTPJl@JGufBZ5XkMOfxYKbAYBBHUdHDH26vb4nn0FPOcFj2fFkJs4M/L30/OwlZHT7XhA7jAVFMYcUumc6oMXQ7Hpw7FsiqyYx2vyYPMoHLSvXcrggW8sn8UOxMDSDr47Hl/nprNGxKx0bKtQd2xadd0bnseDKeaAI4FH@UVE82xPrHK/x8OuGIkdz5NIxUUj5mGM6v43uP6W4OL3ddkDVDXCTZkZfZp1Rl2llliBCoyOtrBBckiJRhtsgEiOO20NjBFk6MgzaFuVWFKUPEtWkTed6PTGBrgZ7JvQ2lqv4V80q5@apqRzjMeSS3cPdU/yUhBgKYdj8@Ey6f4bW0LZP2dA8NfhAcGLhjAmXgVIAcm0aMDv/AWIruERDy6ZZBrzTPBT8ivApcmMpHYm7lpglb36z6lqihTV6SZ2P6eA1sme6FcEvPZeCrwe7Mzc4pYbOWgG7HLJcwz@fohbHnefhwSuCf95OjY56kXGCYZwArTQ4pwaNwtgxzhhqtAL2McA0O8GJD9iKobRfoQ6A2h60LDy@znMqeE4J5MTpJjrQ9HwGb7GPWFYTMCA/RMg/8AdgYNXXFqGDH0TFcrheFypGplF15CvQOkdd8MMd8j75YfyAutFMRwvOyZut@eCw06G0aow3i8CSj1iwdSA9U9HXwLMAOVySk7WEmAKwKTEpctBh/OvRObULxEsq7CakNEMIPqoBCokKwT3TLHLfhgAeD3SXH8rsH253fn4u04mLE8eUDRfvoHDx8mxl3DdBjLYVzxiN/dv@TLzl1Yc7N0n86hm8Un1rSpeZl@/N@FcQem7NX@iSiPfcOHaOZ3jFQn9EpzPhsUguEdSeSdezdBL@uhtOf1ozfRHQXwXpTyrFrxAIYwhmmp6lO2kAlm53TtO9827V9zijBgnAoRaNwBHPQXUCy8gNTOa4F4awPeSjoVd7eEqzrQBJ5OO286R5CYOQs8Dq28fmFCJZxjnbdhx9liD/JIZGAk7MSOxhM@j2yQeM0M2wC34opzltzJoL0adhdOjUAi2JOXj0knBxO1B@Qiv6T7n/FPyn3H86TzRItjFtcpEMna6wOEj1eGJfEBLBzIIwV/w007kPQQbZm6kcBIacLbhdwa9To9gBvrkN6rEWEAbQxBgQbiSUxsuTxknTco3zjWZK6QOxi4QIqHEA3WgSTs@7oRmxPzwbjm13wcnCgxqhV/LzjU6dgU8NnFawjGEFEWFwfJl4tl5/5K9S4AKBX2CAgHIYeKJosO0lzGQ1PBGYPIFwGuIcxzxjDT8zTZK@fC/fDcQljnqO2CigZgQQuodFgmyCDwtaDr9xKOAOLxwbwgRhJbokZYRnPMWbccDktabCeU2VKimSK0kKsgloR3G1dr0ogT9UReOaV6SYV379R7O/9sHZ70G7WJ57IljeYVSFaFPBVX0gQvjNhbDK6rVIvUIOlA19aDjQc@1y@dTvrSGZDSVQM3g6WAT3HK9RTkQqv5Pk9UM7B0VLrISkMKvVoIizGm@WvF0EKOUID6O5frRZQAh@fM5AAEZmaTTDjzaNRpvWapxxsOmKaOeRTE4pk1MehYeershk048G2tN@0L1g9TRBOsVlhyLAU3k3CmLQWGR4lzLOeX@B58/hBKmf5pznEBX4NIQiNtJZp7k09UYk0xGmdQ0AEuINAF1@eWFFuM7wVCm0hTyKozLgUdzmkwHnFUBgxIKr/IzWREhkpAODwC@mqB@AtiumGoKo0uAv/mX4T0wHjsFPvemYWQypLjpm0tf@/lEcm4jZSAONSB9qJocMGTWZ55Z/uGFU5ojhPb8DG6S69rnNEkuEbXBXJn5UpT2028pIx7UreKWZf833eJYM9AecOGH3x7ane3YuV@FKk0lktyx9rjOYfcvGmxAi5zSDrNe1DdeKe1CpHbtvma6RZniE3qnhqx2GfzS@EJWTfaPtCoI/bMnVWATN6QpF3VYLL1lttRK4ui9ZCZcf02I/JM94XED9F0yR@MCefKAH44Td/sLoeMm7YeKh4360Y7NzmjgY@544xLrNgId1QP4H3wFIMMy155ojHWiMonTbS9B1AAN7ZPdB6pu4soCxr4Hfn8PGDOnjMeUlzXRUaSuRo@eplSQ6aT3pR/3kg6OyT7SEngzja4sAFpCRZs51HCNmnSXJtVYmx6MF6R19eH6Povk9uj2/pIVfzzNXzWvc88OSzibmECDgPBvZu7OBRQe@1b2RnYWshM4oV/EI753FLq0N62JOtyHoth9c7gF9pEObC7Yw45@uwv/tFRhE333f6tPx5umjGfCbEa55TNDlNW4wA5qA4PvJpBBbklxI2g/fMy0Ii/eG7aEIAWIsMS4Lz2KFhjkGtdsN7xMIAN9B87gc6wbd0xqtGvdckifnLM1OtdVV9LDVNYb6zOgm/JDpCNygxIegsBG/er@CI6MjpmdzXS8BfVcy9IVuHJHOA1VWkIyePksmV5MVD2KG1EMj5ZTD/dX4Q/8brBmH@Gp8tBr0gHg8hsOxZyYOf45n4xk/7nvIrzDx@Sjvf3hN4vEIdyME8MB7TzU9TzZ5G/s8TIRFeo8eIQwrLxYZT@MNIOLhPzfr8MNQdHdJoXIjkWpBLQuLF10sr3HzthqPUEVAk3xq6f1I8i6ie2@ai5AaBzZnYTsf1oXcgIyLNjqdRBQid7m1xmzrBk9ANxqns1b0Kq0lDDWMSZzOM0ndJvkiKaBmvA9fHHD6FL4IsG94LU5QQdlwTMu/DIyRz0gfR6QW3wWEdIASwSJHuZ@NSCghMEPwi6swzc7KNDs30uwspBm2gMUkI4GEzkKSfi1g9dxWBUOj563gzuiFujN8bmPb8Fi27uBoxUXcjFfMNIufxSvAkONGvLKbAKYc78YrD8ngxitHZDiNVz4Bw7xtxS/jlaBZYAAHrGS4j@4@C0d7J17ZSSSvBE8/NdwgXTleCesUwmxxK2EEUIHlBqkRp9gs2y@m5xjQsZFQmWZIMW4a1Scah0nTLwP//OoautQCPXGMc4MCsxRTFzqNSI/B04FuIzg0fUlLrvi9@e7BHi16CoNgMinQ8aJxCDyI4bH4IjPiGUNfmtGAL2QQ@WZleY5YpCd7z@z4qQOFUiUvpk/Yk0ke6CbIvwGBm/NE6L4iP35QX4sgeAW@Xz4x8qp83shOkBzlCOdkk0uyhUh9Fb@lUFjXi3nxaz9aQzTWvRgIr24PgvBaIrARng4yHE3OYWJje7xIJOSLK@zNaBwalOONEqn3WjTiCn7LXOFNzn7JkDFEG3/ytuJE4mHWFlgQejYyTd7Kwn6BeDF6zXldRFLljQ@yEOE50MKNzindBfXQN1I4zm7S1Fes6oaCuDxJ4lyLbBIiy3je1ET3eOqh8rqLp1B9mPoaxJziWEsCAURihqlw/mp/gPxuc/k9EKgDJFxLYJlgvbwrvSle39rLXsv5cJ7szQpEzzR7mFwqHIUpzFEO2kFEMr@N1m6I@Ljkgwv5PNEQ@jVpP0BbqBPcgbfrugWHhVKCc7boeKqB46m2GlE3JZLhmRwILTKm5MPhBQ9zOi/a7XnlBV9WxehD49v68IMr2Fms4GjlITwqgHMN5byVOxOLVrnM2zawbe6CLFWtMM7Iabo0rOa5I7B7mroNp23B4aB1@PDg6eOvQ6dbLBaTfh89m@cPWy2OtYb9OIdMK6jD/mCJ2qKl8cIWnOzG4Xh3YDve2okl3uAlnFmDMKBDKgH5@W086fOyCD@/1nYhHg8bwagP63TeDPQFroSijo5dtunj1QOEGF5iQ/eBBOIt4DtN2lqSriZptSx9ZLRa1H21Wrh4qdXyezGsmmBGPPmz2JoycR26TJTfq3MuCHSwAnt4wF482j5mx4922d7znU/Y1w@esxfbT49xT/2z5w8e7@8w@O0@PdplwsLSSryDDBVKwOtDo2PgxZJMy2RyjCDv2OMZ5zuJnSR3P9JH7JHdMXCaatPVR/cH3CJbhlfnsXZBHZ3hGKZJd86NTA/XW9AlaaDGonDTpV2BuOCfQdg26LQj1HlHdtfsmRBWQN13bBpusJGMDU2oQeC3wR7jNBeS8D40WjpE9xziCqxziK5DeJy7ATA6X3@FKMYQ/AK1rsx8xIXPB2PwePfwyRHD4xl2Dp4@3D/eP3h6xPYODsH67Ov7Tz8GfO4fHR/uP3iOXhTwycHD/b39nW1y4BnIyP9Pcde71caO5D/TT6HYJLih/Y8EQmJMYsAkniUhw5/k5gDxNXYb@l5j@7oN2Em4Z3Y/7Avsft9H2FeZd5hP@xSz9auSutW2IbmTOWdyTnB3SyqVSqWSVKoqKcRN@OUqHN6LQg7ZmSrNX3HynetT90dvSa03VvDqpsH@kaFauOpC@gSNTvDZby2UnKsQyxf4ZPJRgcrMV/Zfvac5X/m/4YTTHAWz/UHqKOQ7@uYLap1ro8GyQeOt5JhAiJls0eXziMuxwjUdfonjKWT42VMGOBvxtAJfpbZgowLdt4Rd4LFsQFNFDwg2QBmDlbLi63UWFrx1BrlBtTU7PUTIlNrEiFC/oOhLY2pScphi2lYGQOHUUOtCH1QsRR@I7@nDsq52OJAM6nH0QTKoJ/IBS9EabEfUis5xNdy7gnhWq/Lhl8v@Dh8Lq6fRh80G72LXNE7Sb9ylDRVdT4YgFB2@REm0PHzRYyNsBgEXCTk/LhjqdGRg@HK1HclEOUpk2zbKmSJh08ZRgzZ7kxtjkUrcADuhRnsYqkzZzalDGAf53UCurzrvNLpiAhWb7jDvqTXE@ylv6OVDdO0Tu4n0e8yAuHIuiUdUbluvCv3vLUclN6dqbGgbSb560ZigfQuBzSkE/hEwBChxlUejyTMVu6wCTK@tWTkT9ogjobf93c5P7Ny6avqJAtpqK/NL8Pmzq4nsJfZJxk6RsaMu@uwPaFnJR5nt3oDGOItVvigHUrB50esPA@nDTLIFfOLE0xzlxsRGtf1siKtrAx0ma@z2ulalZ8TFd9R6Rkz5PbUyx8vZeSS@4htUifNpEha7O6DTOOtd@9bZmYdDpBsf6hdaCPNZOZSf4yFjIutPJ5YdvytcvLhW3tjePMn@/rOH2xdFLMjlp8boEP@JMVEXDQ8@52ODxQHWXXqkmVuzwqszlNY2eFpaYpQbYLQPvAhoX/eyXorSxNx4@jscaSa/88evX8tSKgvJpG/MDS8ysXTz1LGp0uMyp0qbgFiyk5AlWZ8xXzyGGcnrl3CeQS@UiCJdyBHs2yfupNIixLTu7KpNkkVfDaq7O4Lvqg22qIjvVYZTjN0f@U@ZzfLShpuPDUqURc6MEdGegVx0XcssheerKXDb94Mj@f394NbuxU6mhz8EbfteaH8It@zS3bBkWrJgfT/Y3@8BK5PbPwSW2u7dDVgmyWloEadHzOnNpyNr2vtr/Hmq73jsERjMvdCgRECt2q66fERtAlJnpIBrg4kXRAeH29X9fZWS/QmVJbmHLUNLi0HAfqDexda2QZeFXS5aNNlRpGXxZL4kLNrMv/sG80zi3SEq9BrE0/SIhEV8g3g7GInU0zMLLyHY@p4FoqFcErsvRgaFxxrwLe0BCdm406wGOjObmZbJJwhtI3BNN0/WxrYNP1tYy9yNCzcHYxuQbRPUOIdnyez@@yDr4@emHllgIXAQGtyilTTNN7RPOKCK@5Qxl0v24D3dYroURvaywE4b2sHwq5BcYf84QzEjySJc1sKWWNeLY42arI/nzTKHDRIxDTRg6akTxaKZEoyI5y/rdoe68aSXSU5BtMjEFYwvba6g4qe3egpjakTzZDlakNtjbZ6xOTZYnkI7q2GX7s70ELbQq5PiYbIqkrb3VpX951Qls0SiJkPzmY0xiQR5dWXl8bdgT7bCFM/@KGyZQybl5/CyT/v7GGQ4Dlm9T5xbe@uZ9JgB7iGdmNabATNRkJY6M@aURNt5MrLxI1xEL0TIIDw7brWcrNVVowncZkOXGcmGzlmm2mAN4aihMmqmqH97f3UQyN@s78Efr08GGzLBdPAWVvlveoPQj73yrAAu1ie4vCa/@YNBl7OJP9MloGTYjeleZzv2thODV2kVEvm8zW5JW3snidmtZ3QNXAmrF3O4yBbavdKkei9bLNlN3antVtUih21sJ3SRqUHKtWTPg6B7HwIsg1kvgemDffgehs/pP@HgGZBEJvbmyzBt3G/ixhShVfMxX8@jzUK1bC1O9n47bDa6iPvhpR6GKuU9ooKsha3u7bizNOuFUqI8IRf2uxkq5aWyuRQXpW9Q6AJSEoT0Jr5bExY8NYylJNxrznuwj8LBlj8S7RlbTjbyxbXC6jOHW9f1ht7l8bNTb7FZTimafBvdy/BqcNP69bx3cd1WHdX/5WzUHH/@TamVJ@ox1bX8SGLnFlfLeQ5X@pT@rqlnBeZcjeALjgOMi1VzcuOkUgsq3oeXHii5@IM3zc/hITHBpWrx0nAhXOyG5cvj1dNyt1woXR53T0tw8hsulYdLxaUMPjyiWZRkjJzMHw9PMafaWle/e604dGU6ck2iGRuuIfTlTWMQ9HYrb18ltHFYAEAFpm29WaEul9jOwZoNvie5rn@T0WoyT4FjHSyQnDn2CirCH571yVDHtALCjHrFo9VsOOK/Y9eZK@Su@sMep5iQhmAt9TX46swZN6YCaxQoy3FgAh/Cv4DgxHkyOBiSr2Oxos4WZblWhO@ka4E4RkkWh6mTVAo@hUBU@3Idnzphzm80L4AEbm3@ysXU@jrf4UysFuZYiwdTjsaAHSYKp3jEAQj99Pm0AVXwyj1ktw@Hmo/3Ih7kC@uohuwnwwbyDq8UkQLzb/WF/Zu4/DoRQAg/J2uunFZx6pUXLSTFd5CVC4hrltz445gBbpXSKXNoLGBLfeUYOFuKM41QrSYTfZ@7ATmFVvRPtyBb5LepZkT5XcnOJOFzav0WgpbcpZy0gZ9OXCxjFcuaYiazRYq5b1IDmi7aHr3xaViN1Zbf6RDSQou5mBx4ZP9eXf9SVH94jDpPI@QlPTuVnk2k5yRdkIpz5WiCjzM9tzOl0l/ifLcqFWfzpuoqK1685KinmzlaksR5S/flDXPDXj2IM29EXSlcGSWsJxKyVsqnGb0vKQ8SZSIGj9KPJV3z97Lu@QjLRN6Xyfrx6@gO8tl4VtuaTHBprht0Xjj6wl@dAjZLETWVkuJ8RaAyg6qsfTC1OKEVHPT8PGw3yjGUpaKRODxmUhvrL1M5vch4kZlEQ7wYpwbWjDFiUYnrXGLCjdhhkerh5AcWCIYJRlNm5G6YwmNdeGyBRa4Hplrxgpwa4NS0ySFehl/kV/wxgz2JnMmXnp04J5iPpPHi3ZwkEAvdB6nZZEpKE7iLyEfdqHtmkbju8STE2ULiraUFjur0xQe7DTX4g0hO2ILCSIopukcpmtJxhqJh37u6EIm3zt/zi86rBq2x@x1/pCrYZjTYC8tJOLgP/XAYIgAUx7EJr/r9Dk4decF3wy7UOpbI8gqOW2KI1syec2qw7JH8Hp60QzoVyqk9QL6BgUicEF6dn8OZDB6wvRuIVmhcgmHOqXTHotCgMfN4WdzMfYXgGyyAO8G5jYT0nIweUDrsN5p@zqE1WkirH0ea2g701ZqsT4ffCEKM0ZT23HH@fBU0f916hfPcp8XC46JFsmt9HFzIPX4SO1gRkUzCMsIDrhSfOI51NtyUs@EsAHpqFxP9e@JN/9rvdn2nQjMGZwxp0Rr6g2u/lXOcfT86BAZcsDJOJuGH3bsaNEW5Q4uuBjEjvIRDT47DiMPwi/lZjoubfFbmOTi0ik@bqauvgxYIaDxO2j2cDvOBBcIECD1Q6NIfElEWXZVEic@eNS68drmEIoqogTgn1tlERIZubxg0qWdYk@V0CJQcg8SVdVsTmFB9zU4DzsG5WQjAPSamgEHAHCXdh4OjD83/EA5KN8ycsTdMz@RJ@vV4rNBw9wcBSd@YwNwrXMzCnTr48HXtQB3s7Rx@qOxXFT2/2997X9uubqvNj3zGjYNyDrqrXu/tknSJTtPl1HyPPqQqB1QyxQlO5e1HVf3p3X714EDt7avam3e7NYJG4Pcrbw9r1QNP1d5u7R5t8@k7QVBv9w7Vbu1N7ZCyHe55XKsp5sTl1N6OelPd33pNr5XN2m7t8CPXuFM7fIvKcKpfUe8q@4e1raPdyr56d7T/bu@gqtAwZ7t2sLVbqb2pbueofqpTVd9X3x6qg9eV3d2Jhu59eFvdV2wkYLVys0pYVjZpC4uauJ3btf3q1iEaFD9tEfEIwV1PHbyrbtXwUP2pSs2p7H/0NNCD6p@PKBMlqu3Km8orapyT@QZVqF@2jvarCJEEShwcbR4c1g6PDqvq1d7eNtP6oLr/vrZVPSgpZ3fvgAl2dFD1FG4P5KoJBlGL0ul58@igxnSrvT2kOePoHewdXOrkD0QYwrJCRbeZwDCDQGuJSHv7HwEVdOAO8NSH11X6vg@aMrUqoAIsKrYO7WxUIRHx0G6melt9tVt7VX27VUXyHsB8qB1UXeqw2gEy1GCQ8ZFYhyo94lajnwgveSRmdQznetydqrajKtvva8Bc5yYOOKhpbmGybb3WNM8hEK@lRAl60Bk0Lm3FSnv607WPCJTTGpnZOpooYtLW3naVZmQdzyoVJxzRrLM2EUrJTqOZJkqk10TImpZ/dnVeD7rtHnxMo2Ki@LgMzz1clOPilpET5557orR@hQuk0/X6@0qdNroH9brrfU/JBBrfKqHV4PflcnUbcaMBdt5Q/Dx/LnRfTxBq45E@6GRDPRxAIKdQ/5GYvjUufVfl8y1fF4PzPgAb1VEoxyYXOEoh0cjOjrgeJa6SNRP8Hmh24IIZAz7XrENPCstIztQL6U/3a/wik4P1gaSzqLvyeWxiGY3gs2@qkUo4JAL/0REJgjZXmQt9/9fzTMGuDnv@3Hmv18q4rinDeYe0DzzPuN8ofuafTxTPTpZnZPnYWd8SEJp9Ny9hovNnTTKl@yU34JZl8Kc@5B/XYCMxH6A15apYWa2VlplHUhwWSZ7SoS3gXsGdjDXfm8pPtQ/YzRWWn5Qmvr@OvsvYgr0gItXShHfM5U755/WpZKABxrE4iCSBjpCRz1tljL1JlPmGMl4g003QguUPzdUXPs/rRBJayF41OnadmI0HwcjGnuTwq/3Km82jnR0SncD2ydrK09WSE4Xd@smT34@oh8PJctSxPs3jtE7jJGuUbNHCh0eKFcY7Zn9m4HweGRGs3XQaf0Sch8huI2nJBEGG5oa4K6gLE72UDzqkFAfgeOAYfp05MjUDZBJNddGay8aIl/gNWisxD2hjls6Ye22EP4AdDX8zxKMGaQbSLMYBdolzaXfBci@1Y0xFeXPDgXuQJZcyfCxh3CIasKqL7WfhXctvmretXgzFlBHjlbudSxISDyaxUMauoisj@x3HGdEKYI4eRl9@0vxGjx91gDsOd9cIh5XhAZFxJyoJPXWsjNaNPtaQT3FxBoKqmZrWFbT8rkaKx55WJ0eBQazRwKjghhXY@CYBl6I4IpNVsgXsywVXfRFORfAOwClpjtXvxLmzmqOhlEz8EP1uolIogRUFORGq3UR1OCbLxyiOhSFngkw/RA@G/y@kyQz467TjJOgxtawggN9FSYYqtKLtKxMluDEHDdbpRkxN@9PHGMyt3TEXUcP06c1I/GuIBLp3xubDRw572M7MIACYHIoNe/xGJmkXDdo6vUy5ujjOSbrNy35G6bnCTBVTcLOrpx4vuzxztoIXV7mia7Iq3KWi6qVs3M541NOWaWIrrx6GKQHnmvgf@UVWgEQDnrn0QqxWJzmroEeZkQM61JI14bSiiEm0LL2989RuUVkhMhOyX598GUIR6A3gM91OvkWkp8Q8NxlxkWdidchR8BA0HNtkTD46ZN0ZG2J2fMB52GJlCC4aGd5ggugIdA7VF0NTmYdsKIJKYqvDOM4gxK2bI9LytHoTYc@aSXBohP1RV6LV@6LVMjlyEuBDY2i7y@fUm8aYUO58X7OFxfKLBz0PtouoTNQSujwuVWn2egNaOjbQbsLRC8ZuTn3QSge/G14NdPxCms@CgdZImEU/VYNlk@zeeZqRQPGMWhgM4a3QyjF/cJMufViISniSUXZVZYh5DY9uGKVjMFoqqsx6nLJONOGwpEzEdbWqvn6VXEJQHTLUZwoGYbS5YJtNrgfnDtHwu@kNfsXcjyVQt@W3osikFkjWBUon1boc47E5lKb3eyFrNKgroAGJKFEURVpkqEpz9FPNTtquKRVHx0TsUm7JH68nYlJjLUUVxYyrayfmW81SZ4JKyzo0aBQstLi8wqjM2nDd3rkZ42ihyWNrlTrpRiLluSwiyg/N0hFPIjejp4940kr@8sMQo4e@4IxbL0GBMNasOFedlnOMH2wKPgT@oGXrRGkl02r0oX7jrU@vy7xoVIc67F@zMQz9Me0AmvlglGcY9cyfehfd@lav0zgPekGD9mmI9T4SiYfHMT@iw84HvZuQ7wvihJaVqTWOnyW@jIRhw3t0LlmyQnOFQ7@fsc0UhoNx5ULCRLDmHEaA8QWezN/9yRhpUZknK3EhJ@l/yvZ4Rbd0Z9nHxVmF5UQfALSA25iwoBAf0iE7JlnOp6WpDGf3ZbBwPFNZ1XDvsNhLYPyMSMTHMAmMDTJTZgl2I7AzuxPj49bIa3EMwgECLfnbPu67CTP82WvgTmSSIi9gKfBcFdcKVlE5RRkhDiEexneTe/npvxh7QuAH0C8@nsUtsxiBRVzbRFsKZb@io4wSLmweGLCMZklMUiw4D7qW@yHfNDGahJpMHt9FDbb8oUWRDrM3xZUYkRna@OBau0ydRE597GJSWVALLsftwBKkMswU7mZY/1v2szz4cYgrmjMIpi0NOWMhfRepmkQl3Do7YV5roywxlb89YpaXv7fXJghYnmVyZt1@nEmZlQt7oAQyv@JYqzcgYZyaoJ429VgIh73@wndS707ZMTMy2yxaN133m4bAwmxlmiwXW0za8hiP45Izic8E0yQpxpZmxEPYvvJzxOaTRByV6xhv5fr4G3S4i2ax3VQ0qUT93ZKxj0nxGha9ZqKJhhTjjiClpej7cZ0aXr9bgmiYsr2qs8SoQ2TUx/JogZogU0Sl76cQc5/GfYIeLaIc6m0R7ez@uZOok0ZyJuSpSUoEuQQ9EbgdTpskl/ptGF8gTJyscCMhFS04R96Yj/KK2TMEGUaCAMSq2M/GeijR4MadNcFHfDtAO1OHtVARkoieNmwLhyjof0QwjsqvlTva4qE@zhZPSwJpFEGiXQXnug@S8Ten1@P6iKFMkYKG@AxSRC2akk0X39@qH20L5SMIUpqTtaVvwUNjXLVE2NAfO6k@who4rkqXTIyo5ECos2igsUC7lPOOL9tVrP6CgXA8rBv0MKINhHzO4GdJl0A479VCRG0UGbXGyOJqcstoc1V2Q4rEDCXvIL8eirLU5Y0rAfAFYypfLhIEhDVl7HEowKF3bM5LIKr7iAqWixiW9JGjosZ2njPSQVSd4cmKlaMwK8czG0Z2JhBaWMzOEyNCa5bZWWIoNNHNxMXK8XR2e@IctCA2vC8Up67QvZKkYdRzQkC@sbngxhLluKi8guZgTnyy4iYSI/7m1GcFK7UwmUr0iTA8zhYnU9cKidREtcvLyaKJkkQP1641kUikcG2EI6nwY//YNcUOeR7ZhFqbjMQqQ9tn40Zt2mXSvi33S6jW2SnbrDEMPNsz3Gy/6nLFSiIo@/0B2NUCHxkgdvsPt9ZYphpM9F0BHJfOOLtkZEPIK9YUpno0CztdE2kvClBg9rS9tnp/uLOTCPt6NjaGRpf@YKVQKICJz@zg98a2GqqkoJdP5s63rzqdfP/mT4P3Z3mW/b7PVwI8Nzton7qEBkWY6w3O5WYI4EBZkTurHVmx179qt@0rGHBCic6jbpOcOhqC4gkoiIxe3h@yAohB6gn2ZzQQ7ftZRaPvpiELTQ3FHENRaZgEX6fM6RmRBx/asM@OTqoYGASzsWaiecstb3zBDIKbTbizOHyx@yU2T0699judnqc@4MZhRAqYu50ssLNjFyhIFpwwsnfvVcjxaD3lXwcdy68YWWxeBzgzMZl7JkxceMTG3/fPq6N@JnX8KUXTCjV5Cc1cQnxqT6XOU64OFv8dYIUPCe3vyn3Z6GeaTKfJzDTV6xEcPxFGj4vezL1PIovLOjFNs2/nBlFno5vjYA3UdJfXAiaWPXcvt@SO7BFxUyejYhs0LAgMjRNirnxfCbia/evE4vWw3f4@qcjXAEjH/iGJKDeh/JhA5DMAHoF6@BE9EUX737I0rHcmAorIAgeXdUzLHRSoo4DjPGyWf7vJVCoVNd9fWlKVyiY9ZLOqsllR2/iwuam26X0T74/KyysrJZG52@4X@rhpPt6qTYLBGs6l5sVgm14prQy/MVhro4vn8@V5rzRfL69vlML8cWUTbv309Ld//8@//cd/5Sv65X/wsskvx5@iTLlcLj/f/DL/6LaE9@Pt04X5s@P5/unCeQlc9neOGt6rDbON2Hw0Nzhz0jILWF/ZjtTsszn6jC6qzEWAl43BryRdnqt0M8yn9ddQbo5iGZtu@tZ3H36UZ7SFN5cOTG7lCYk0AR1DHU@90/RhgEfzDVGScIEdqJSXsxWjuEc4mChDdKqS1pF4eM167cOnJY6kAF9cmrGyQTf0u9CAX/OaV5rnOA36DYZ1zb/5T2/C883eSC2eZNRiQS16ajGV4p/i6jP66s7nA3jnSjbaDqRSHqXERwswM1RhwAs93j/wXTsT5Haceb6yB5BMmArOLF5wXrT7Y2cZuXAtPHfmcN@mEhUJHzKhSPrLfPeWuuUL5bhNJVxteKFQ17sYrsw6UYn6F0ugRiiGAHHNl0KQ5z2qEid97JGMp7z5ovva4duEGDDIuv9qh8c9PtBcNN/VNs@JvRSuOWLzefmKubEkztCMNlKk/hgBPlCR7WSBPQkX0guOWHlbreRmihe23T7NfGLrMPaHxjZdCv2uLCYQa26bcPNd7deiDbnleEWlguh4xaoqNWn7rRyryOVVZxj0tbsC144B9SWq7VZGEnqUAQkcidn/fHqEsaLARIqa6Ba5LGusWj00XUZCV7umUwe7OTk5soiQ/5Shsf11Ymy7efYSMewgPMBIRaZ87UbQCXXUlQET@7wxOMPtgI02X6g2lHMz1ufhitUJjHvtCOkcQ2aT83g8U1PS/UHj/LLhqfTb3uGgMa7RtEUrn2Ez51ILEYIJSGDw6apnNc8gLC3SXcIUiZrClkO4vKAz1tejSd@mIp8TdKkZCjrsCgZBgp2Ykv7XRF9N0DHm6j/QCTbKU8I7Oo3UIpYlLyyNNKSU7TbDw2xq6DimBnvsRAMn5Qiq0cg0vKALXWGiveSDX5LkHcQI0HWntBegdkVYfYb6MTud@91GYnLqdxzj6J8vKZkXMZ75KkqxRnLM5ajF@MY7YEXryE/JKBAyN5lwRs5cJjN3Eurr3NL2PMJBviNb/HxDBdEFdHyBGXuGqKNuIMJyYoaK78DIqRpb/hOEdqdxTviNbxpjsOJJOvPiQd49/nTSPV3MnHS/nnx2GRMtks0sm1VpfZhtJJYeKzQz5r3Eq7FKC02owZNuMsNJV4kPi0UCQiSfOf6UP/2aJ4RO0rh4/iQtBEl0GTDJ319fHuDzU2imk1jk086cu@iazs@8KLqK5lb@RR/KB1d@CQuzqWQ1Pe1zBm0CxX66v12Jy0mYX1suPFkuPqGd0Lk/yg78K8y32fDqzB/RUiLEdpamnpPPCW5IEOJ2FDZK9HFE7ZRrTcT3JNROSlqE6mHO9TgRW1GZnPAE5Scqc7hUuLi4UZ4GDh@x4fcUsZzJy7GgxHTQ4r4M5s@wd4l6GiHk2qR3iHAkrAzERoRVqFlANpev3MWhrhkuC@znlFNbiN3KQKh782lrtuj2ulm9WHNzCyUsouE101krrBUmx@jUEE2M0Hm9mFp4oIobL57@9b/3fksP0xvL@Q8D@h2mf0uvrqXlkR7o7bF5u05vpNeRbfU2Pc7THpgen/71f6n8xp8IDlLG6/RnY8XAWh2nN7JlLvI1vbFKD8XlZar3//7yF2rDvOzYcBfrfN1TjFjJUGSr0WXepXRVQytlW7oQixV2zAIMsTCkvTm9wDBqtLxWYDVdWltVXPs68pWxR9FTPBtmDdlUSDQZxp6CVkZSoIwKsgLSmFC0lWW7Ycw2wLwxmurnh7nVkHYAP2tzjqjKyHTjYQiToXnZFlEHZqRG2s/Lw0bhRSoy73ieMjYlJbOExNZOy9q1x6X/Bw)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/pe369)

Ruby with `-x` [flag](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/options.html) searches for the first line that starts with `#!` and contains `ruby`, and starts executing from there.

The code:

```rb
#!ruby
puts 339
__END__
```

Answer (score 1):

## 348. [Pyxplot](http://pyxplot.org.uk), 15825 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                #  ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc11                                          #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-'4o'6o@@+.---@._+>$] )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMM M''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\` #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68));                   exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #    wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
set pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl6154op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92g=1*\0C0ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40dHw/IgUqFskRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7p3qpStaS6dftSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpO9ptj293z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipqm1HTGwsJAKJfJw8eTLz5Dn5OGjr3uBnP4vhxZ461qxvOWM2Nrwx67rmqeHK7N6M3dVNL69lBQFjbbv9ydCwx15FiDGVMUu3@xO9b7CeaY0NN808w2Btw3LOIFxjbHNiTzyjW4e3LGO2ccb27I7ZBQhs7JwYtvnGcCEsx9h9w7oYXoxZxxkOdbvrsZFr2mMKzTP2VIeX3qRzwvS2N3b1zth0bAgqMPbMtvRhu6szij5yDZ6oyABU54TSLIaUGHvsuJ4BOTgdw/Mc9CyDp@6azqPtJx9fia9m2Mc6IDWyjOmV7FWVPTcNt3s1hcY@O3rw4Kpvln0qOTZ7cB0lNce2J2Nnb3wVfp5t9w1bZ5pclrWrgQUg5tiwSplSZiEIwh6YLtSi7tcW6@g21ArW2QYzhqPxjEm8nnXLCuvQY7rHJt5EtyiePRm2DTeI6I11d2zafXZmjgdsPDC9MB3F9kZ6x5C6hmUOzbHRZZYJiZyeDwVA2112YszOHBeq1ofp2NYMEhods2dikgAPAIhXYjwwOJyhPoPKtMfQCJjOPEDDMgJoSSEG8e8b7UmfOZPxaDJmgFvX9PS2BUDbM9Y1evrEGqdZG8KAmOR/NjBsv9ECOBlAHDkcq1cTQs2Yt22922UZaK@Ax4nBTKAaoVVh2Sz4M8cFqkGsACMfGLVfXkZjCnUDVd5zKiyfyUD4buiD2OqW5/jILKKGgTb0SaozhPvUdfquPgRqdA2i6Wd7T5nXcVx4gx/G5f3mJjAdfcw2N1l898n9OKuH1SK7bSGsoho7hyqIBYHsVLcm0EKiNeFA/bhhagGrLL4Wr7A4kEXLsFyO5aB7lpiWByKpmTI4oJ9rWRV@BaaVWE6FnpKPpzGfnqv3TcvgUPoIpYgNXMszDe6ZHMuqJR6z71g9Hq1DmRVZtsQKRVbMsyLcy6ysQW4IOsfUch5@BfgBtDKgosIvm@OA5u0e2im2tR3W04emNfOhE/gOy6usCBABXxUgayWAAM9sFn9Z@BFai1cU9ngA1B7opwBesswT5DpGyHiwChV4KBsbCnE@ZK08e2@A2QPpgGj5EitC9gWgRA5QAMpqJY0XwhsYluUnGXiYhDAtZuAHWBeBBiWgfAbomEFCFuEH78DTNGBeGnAqDZiPpoK/Bu4sgod4BQgrQDUWfFoNdO8EMuL5aF0iPHBtAKMipZFRqUgggAA1xbJQXwWWg0aQxUaQzzLAHXApFhjwqpLKSjlWKjKgZTnDoF5UwAtbiAo8UgV8VAQGda9C5auAkwqUVgGoms0zIUJoNYvhkDYLaYEsag7S5MANlaYW8AfpoFWokKUKeWpaed4AATctD@XNZ6llagWo2SKEAd00wFWDpqQBtloJwjFtCWhYwoZbjKc5IXSkA9QINnVog0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPt0YDvW2MzQ5P2e5h0gJ2gQKSEZJmsHjwzCE1AZUMgMEeAOhrUPtZIEcWqjabw@wvBei8fEiOsj7gEM@x2yMjQ2YNjMohNjxvjwk7YDVJ4IyLXBPYmAXtEoaKjo4sDTu4QQwqgGOOZQaZwPhpOKc43hOXWcjGI07UdnF4h2Gja7guw7ggE3hp4lnepO0Zryc4MM3x6gETNIBX9nTTChGgjqmPiaPCM@5BfrNFtHuuM6TeO0SeZDnOaAX/Bw54hoAeOmfGHPU5g9RHIwuGIfA3@CgIyJzpJKiQVBPNlSMEiTBdZ2ACQMoK2LfpGh2ivV90SJ0FRr@IYoVp9TtZhHIvMj5l2cgB3u1hGntiWRUYOIwOy9aVrnGqoA8fwxbHLsQhGNVgbPJBtHUQMhBzwiKEdEeTabw8CmrWc4aLReMMay8s@sDEkcY602dQez3gVcZUH4IoxFDesGF0HEKL4TWINQHCHhZrj3UdOz4OoZy5IBVAocOSkOSBNBmbQwPERgeSYI3nCGlkl4RZewZNmaiVk0lO5JhcIZQsXCUU98hFPHhngfGzO@kg1TBv06YWBOOOh0KTa@hd7ieMXXZ8rMPPhQFy5IvGMjow4iGiFpHgYHQ1gPq@KNMhiDjoG7YH8pgnMxMFV2j5facHje3MhLKDqARJ57A7RAQkQeg1lTuyQCTHBjQ8sZjJOqMRA38QQKB5PsiUYEx3XpnsDQRaA5DJOhPXnbHpCGrCHEKsccfp9aD1vjFGAwDBhl3WmXWge0IlY@sRug5xpM5osZjzt3UD4tgo5e08/RrrG0B2kAB6KNZjk58XYDSiIhApdJtLB7YOlMIidEYzIguACVP0HEdG/65jeNRYHPck7PqYmWf0qWtAP@vNmdEQpR1opTZJaV3gPH73QviYobC0MJiV3wo@NmzoOh1oldDpofqwTrdZD7STiEyAgpve6Rijsd9OHGJnph0RoPYfoABFvpIPTPYGwvpdtnml1UDUsOVEhAMUKBH1kS/X6chrfRUIxAXbmMvwnLNYs2vZQ4zTK7mLLzHOAgYvxRU4jKhLoDRJTGIyRlaC3NHsDJAXjpHbkAADvc2dXC8@@EWzd4dM6oV5IzYqsB1BVkIvxGM1DAl@1nVA8shCWPUFD4y64HELaN0bLoHshEha3aivrOgyMMXbgA4d21kCFYgZwsUoiyFUF9QYD5Fr6FbYGKm7eAt1hAx7rpXjQAZj6GjkuNAzONOZkWpGVRZpXb5GkwjHiiRo9ItDKwwZcRzwxzgKQoKRBXocdTHsqSCq6sApgIlxjQN4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidEevnjQnGUts2UNrV3RkHAsWD4RkymjHTdYENnuIgwcegYDCRqZ3CmAC6F3JWJAf1@6uZy9iidyZtc3pVremgp/zKE051l/VQo3FB6IBOlIj3vHiySv6UMhIkKs5orFBSfhchIkWSocoTPVCSYJB4AIzmcGZ3EuJCFxPTTJyMeyUxCQ5MyGU09ok@Gl/F7hX4YaMZnkC/prcq68PwLUlwl9CPMMEARcYA3QU5AzohiO7lcretswvgHqCeT3coNQqZ9FTlXJiXYXfDvHxCIC7R8so8C8/tkEOKjGpYAoxOJadBYoGA70kJSiiCh6L4Yyt6kLTHw0iu4Z4TmyYwWIKLIkl2Hgr7MAAkCBkThA@zY45bvrhy504guKzVatDYQJoCttlNRtWEYKZHBk4NkWWSRvxM5LFzOMa@kUhCeTHyJccGxCZoqbU6Ox8PXOhx9H4pQCQgq2BjSw4I69fzE/Nk0r1a0TZ6YiQRex0ITWZnLFYFGPx5b6jdRNX4AlVBlYgjVbHxYnoCfa3xki9WqOhHcw0Pxd@aj0qkhhOIgd9Wl5KIJ/X95g16Z9axfJGAu6Czc27UBvRP/JmBkBGlfZkg6LTXeioHgt2Bw2FPt48e1vy@yAOVtmlXFjwsp6Nb5L2O0cUg7aO9ewfbB19rLYFhme3KVQ/FzJUKONROplLfnig5WausR2HMAd9v3QwbEy7GEQU/mEnONCIqzTowuEwDcu4ffHqVJCAJITkoB3Dj74pIw@OA0CW0dW9wZRBm/VQKsgyTBHGZtMcCmKEDUcdwPcDn6eTNG6y8q0iNfH/EzJroHEDgqezZQToZA68IYEFQu8dHREoLUqhp4wzt3BWNGeDzMUrNV5EhUTrSZD7ef7B7UCOw/mSFRFEUbwyylO52ZWjz1qRrCMviAPsDV4el5DniKE8TrksJ3OksEHhet2wFfACAuo7sMMkaBkXzBoD7ztWyka/UCVsAvROEq3JlVB7qfCiiETxwiOugyrtsFKWA@WAVei0dscLQxWGrk88bxVw5Omx15nl2o0BplhXGgUBudCHoxJPQR55Lkb5Y7aN/@Oga4h4JkaAKSAFmnsVkysuzBNReJJPFPWUHNDTHMuTnxPFEJiYVJR5MtModj5TPSPzdqTlOZJL8qSYhLuS@vb2n3Q8i@3OANJNBSgPq4jgyuT1cGOl40EZsx3L6DtuANFw6DDIEsWllMbf7jn2thnT0xKLGcG0F@C9O3OgjGGvMN6Q4UqqouspXaXTbOwMurRaySCSiEIFSKL78Sj/VgVzzch/ufbELg4iaz2RCd4YuIEEkDZELXZ2IL3kwCTKSfXyWFjBcZ7nW24MAKbLQgYX2GV2YcHsevNSTOKasLI2/FKVPnGsUf@XMrjQt8OFNCxwRku09efpo78nu4@3Pj8daPr/wnsuUC0A4yK8NspA84HTD3rrBuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xAQQmm3yeeC4xbxigyR2BFq@ErVIlPnIEd95JXC3OGodIru8Ob0GPsfDyqnxAU7a6FyojLl/lwPMf2MxiPR15FUaCXDyZtGZRW5VXHsfS@QulgYLAsRUXVZW8f5zW8ZSkAGW9m8BR8cgtEhxnNIOrW0AHlhRYLkTWwBAdPs1aW2R@ALowrioablMMWTKVRuqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1StxNu1mtFyihhEW@j@EHetZ4DqlIDRCkiRvPLKju8c32Ez4NII6SqQGJM3aJLDYzgWWAwESZo1RT0/IA5xC5wvRV5BNHo9wdlc4FJKPpMrqoW8AmoZqGkgs0o45yYN9XFnII0dCeBJTo/mDSKtsOd1dLsnb/iOAFmQ@z6ComYbL46P7SYI6Md3CDdcyGvMmg21mayy60k2/PjJKrTeheJh2w08oO2SE5omPdkKftbVr7Ozrk69q8uU8XDkjznSiD3eBkHqjQP8umtE@x4mUKKBysZCXAUjv1WWTAhZmFTAG1JKgQ4FIy00PQXxkkDoRfEQWg7wrUgCNp/N4OXgC@MRPoJKN7Z704l7NPOPcg3OlnojICJNNneQS3s4PziG0TFs@ciloXKRSbMzI47z6LrHZyshkb9oGqQHXS2EQLPy4Yy0HS4HQyOgVKSeA@eAdoXTpoP5LCMq/dDSIEPCCScfQIKwafWgD3wGEvOCbPOC8JzIZ7FIJ7ZzZiO0tsFKUtsc88l@Z@Li4qHZjZYNomc1HgegUeEifJ1WGdtGh8@y8sRUClACdTY0hg5OJYB0RazAoCLofIUSdUEPZ6yhW2UkXIYB@BK7uwNcrGPw@SJpiEoUNKldFh@7yrb0haJLb6A13yBbYeG3o0vsVOlHAQEW14tplsSfASXpxBlSpOc034KB9wJxVxjNxgMoMbQwUa85I8O@qvNxjTCRrNK6bjwODN@0E@fxtbW1eCVej6fBtQWuTXRtoSsFri1ySeTCeDK6KEWaXBjaoBTo14xfNgLI02QT28AUJYc35iihNyqVbDOtN1T/qeEzCVUBlIfYEj4ATjxZq6EzmRTrZ7hmA/J7pOw72HYOO6458knwCQgE/N2nQZaIAOo9SvOuUUXd9GaKDGsuKI0GipgJN37cyBw3j8@Pu6njy3gaUyereg30Q2Be48RQ7rvOZASCWyNXkYC3JRvZSrParsUz8Y1EoiRZkJGeTH5USqZ0TutE3IA2lTg@jgNJfeo0OgOX4E3TWjIZEgrw6JmgZVhWIi6flyD/drKZTMUhbTKeBrZci8eBLh0kgkeFxhkB3ogemFMgJXRMGOKiawrEIGlxCrvrF8ZoMHOjEcJZN5CycQZ9vviPeySQi0e55BuePirQLWj6gdzL44Fwi5N3KC@NZpy7CxzTY2Vh60ow7p5KvaEz1pXPZFCa5MhwGV@LK5IEIyGFcEhU7Memh11Ytw1n4kVnGpdOgGLu4Hs0mACzDPb1pKFVmSPB6AwcFl@/C9BZuN6DQwkuXUl8ASwA0O3I8EMmilIJLpaAdEE7NEzgi7S3hWZlVEKCs55gbj5fGL2Ww9yqlIZlMCOzbzuuIQFJIIVA21FoM5NQZ/6OmD2a@bq2LuGH0pCGirdpAEd8YDk60Zaz68h60GgYSQ/6OSQ5MLqCBfyjB@xR5nXhGl1lQ6BVWscdwAgBpUFOrIW1NfQDFMcbdeXxFJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh84x1NU0rdPK9ShCGrQKIPYBKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzLp4UCHf3J/v1dPndCgy0OrziP1ho63QnIlb7edGDY/TTbhfZk2s7QBDIE6d@cWAeOM@ZaPrysmpnhSrM5nFg6zflcnZa5MV3HaTsWTQXdlHQef@J6uqXzSaggdPuzxyDrPzs6rMmVSCRFPx3emDfOQy7PltNzL7rmSOutwfKQxxumuJ4XcdwKtsshm/EDChgw8TfLQR0F/kX0D7oUrqH4/iX0H@JGOZCV/VkEeg09/Yhlioib53AHke95rmYu0X@lDhbGUykeFxzn2J6rGvmfjnu9Be8seZ9IyJqsuXeOvPkmugUdMYpSnkfCHXULcaKAChQn3Fh3NZ7PvMK9BgPDClYQD0AwwVUyGNstFJ9AN0FJnO99M0CQHuFiCHFoXGJjHZA1vWvTFtCnRhKPLcTWqJ/AGKag5CKsK8yf4q5ST7Edf2nS49zTAdWeZk8263wxG1Unl2ttCp98X28BiM16NdiotCoa5hSPh9EIKuEGKaiYtH5/rajhbgyP5tQFSlIVPAW0hqmWkY6nxd3mRVzxiAw9Jh4fTz/KaJ@D@oG7zNbvKH2jihmuolc1CIn7omp7xiQQ7DAWn5/uDICdsNR0kZRQPxO751hdiS@GQbtgXI3CCvL3IoS73/xNjobpBhvfaOchT4psNLJn7hrcK1Vavx4hsssuBAS95JxdnKRPL1gDRrZT2RtZ5rjJLuWx0xogScYT1766H4@Lmq6rzzzB38pSY9sHH3/WyDQ5BGGo4wJXidfiNNjWCfIxyEO4zxZcuCFnbI5pwKcNByaWV5UBqSmthQD6AINnUGVhRn6JEPUL42Jelp4BCmnCQMy92TDNjOSl3LP08diweZvjq4yryc2Xg/xsapT9lr@2UGEZWoABAdTEMECxyg6P7u8eHMjQcr1EfBcXairQHfXOAOSQVYUOKBktfIV91I2zjzBNErVzAboaKBktPz006io0elAzIHdkEX3DTYBnEtdYOuBNy1qUkAtiPoFwW1VnTDQKgSWMJJSJgFWW4v/M5hqVj2cFWnyKKAnkTtypAG3NpDyxzdeyB@MJiacQJc51UhgWausJYmrrapJaj2sOcYUYFCmSDaEEjQaT3gDTg8giazarfKkf4qKe5faRuqJIVUG7f2tqUPU18AbJhSD4yWtv2YtGRio3U@vLQNEeMn/jLi9/BC5CWATtGUuzXU9Qf7/WkTkOfMmPM/JnpDVf2Z1eYevcIfKpZYoe7IsipkPbqBa3Qy1utoJOhqyEZlywIAFLiPnbqv02S@HE@UG1wWTkkUiy85DoGpKcXVwQDdm6xoiG4FIZr4zLQMkExvTIgdI88rdUR4UA6q3@fhHss8eCGGhTiwuyGMIldeX0ihAqnYrRdFwINO0Th5Z1QlcrI6t5FPzC1MMT63rKnukN6LYQNcSBx9VWYecN2z26LYlAqxv@ujl50Ly5L/KCrKgrB/SgKfQlOS/uFVnItm30JnafFhnRzaTXt8SUyiWK3Gu3zVVRgQi4/St4LokGTArbsybnZDXYo40zLjAeAePiSsq86Fe3GbEFusPoMIZU/vO/fL0L9L9eOwMYKHCCMXS0YOjGmpJ6KyvLT4ovdFtesXwefGKZOhGGXLeB7OguFEm3Qsdy0LTWLkkw/A9x5cCvcWibeAPh8IZmxjHnC3/Bc3kmy9bObGCZnVVxr2y74lnRKg/ob10iAheCTIMSEevilWBM@UpLRJNGNnY7UsHeKEaNmdf7YDKe8DvIp7dWojnC301904@Zyett1QANUW@bxg1V7uonk64jjU76oZxaWBJ3Xnpa6pVAHPBXfVvoXF58XkDX7MM4GzxXRZsPbcoZPW5rFZ498UZSm5TtLn@jjjC8IQfX4vdVUUz/cFPoWE0106Lbe7ZEHzo0FH/Tg4JbSqUI0cwrZLb09gxlkMGHt7JwAwFwnFonlcpkV6wgj0ar06PCSOnL5eWpp3KH02PZVIDCt61KfLKMCuxvZL2lVmG4Moe6JWndiHMlM1@2/@Ba1HDpktIYp7hwc7q05ubUxwGpM7F0d@66oYnP8QhWC1ZNPPvDxlOz44A4MGJqUVa1YOiIDBjEMoMdcPOMcNcw3SK7HMxlZOyCWoiDuBS6lrMApzPGnaEr2tR7MDS@IxP3vUYaieysolTHOcPfSvFhAKopvy8f0d4sxeo9mJNkdSwdxvGVw8HCHCDOMd7SUM9Mz6DbcsKeLEV03LGW@i92gWB2Lzpbd1uz9kzL8dgh3W8iUN8FKvD78gYdpaWp2xLNeUfdN/CgYCvDvEJ1q@9YhVJf0eG2stYnbg/5vv98Xw4XcihVvYVDBeKPY6v@cyVfP1Hck9sqiA56ubiNNeK8YYhdxqb8JZbVpQPFANfnlpfsQaZEKWWFz@ityBhXVs70WfD8OYaOVaQNho7RjMRpkO4wQbkEjrHLReyfJ7fczbl1348pXQNbvK0Qkco9sQwYrOh@rUqZllE/MIWaybw/i@pZE2NiLFU09tuvDDx2fIOS8f5IZfxirPsT8rgGgCdQwlhvfM3wvbDGcRrfbmQmumV2jNtFmUWmNgLpe4Sq81NwPEXH9RR9ezJaqNUF7cw@uJlkg1HQpZ3uAnYY8qF8qHSLpLQgn3sG/W7UmLiGh/vAarlMJuMLMJGFlYWXmzSpbJj2lcnvCxmTzzzneVxcTHMjzuV5EFmiOw1XsiBtlWJPkctlxTZtYzzD@3ty07bjWB9SU8BUuyaKYiBZ0o7am2rsmrjjnxVh86kLDyc82r1VkxZ8tPF1S6APKs03VXp05ee9alPCtc0hrjstvt48fRNZR7otFzyvjXNCfI@ttVqW9GdDVLkkF2/sdVxCddqGpfPHtJC7CV5Zzt4Ib5Fp@GuyuIbLV27nK@6xK0xpNANimV3QUgbG0KDXG6R8vYumBfzHykhTB3@rgqeG0VGmu0ZnVYSRCXzBxvvCUnFEWBo7NuhXY9zOh3qKhRtGfd9VHDhY3FtK5L2h3je4TYubOOV8wgI3zXC1bu5cPnVR4RtlOpBsbsRgdZOATnVizLzguRTg41kH6nUyvH267Urn7@Ac6Hv09lU7Va8PsfbAGdgDY8C3h4dvqzoHtMcxt0FyE@qAdX@AO9ZGo4Wd7FF6Wo5lvQ89kTVyRuk4vaU47eIZVzyg9UFwZ3obAvzHrZN3@pjzDnSs7DUDYwLjkueMnZEh0duqqBZO9PD7Kh4arEX/vDNIN@r5QJHg@fPCv1W37OvOeDSiR2tkTTy6UVKJjibfJjf1@A4U2vvouH35jTNsy76n7G9PoSXw5SymbY47Azwbzlu20XfanYF5G9JtQx/b5okSTPnw1/fSXZEyJpPuo7dsmUBedyZje6lFww/xsbeq0v3ZIz6shY4b5JVlM3R0@loa6Scdj8@GootVcEI40hv5Ge0KnXKvvJ6Y4znQyJalcHqXL0ugYxXu/iaJlZIVHYWYs2F/88TKVkpCOgrkkpEBgUddle3idrZIF8tm@W0VQtFSEkaR7ScfQm5/iw/NDpqReVvwX2hfC3uTlg5y9mDS964zTD5d3wURDW@rpy1oy3JkyhrGLN32H6vIrFkKnmWEZwtkrolx45pK/sZFFYqnWpLumPBowQOqbrJyDs0yRx6/M6m3cinO37IEuvjV9UJOm9lyZdqvmK7R40sg6LpNRBw6Lm44BhlE6uBKOs6gIzPnghdnXLbTB6YuWWweOYi7SmxZuhtoefWHY6b0@ROjr@OW6kfmGPdkLmkV1GSX7SK6FfZXJ7pnfnUCJVvV2NAwA1@GdKMn@PFtCbzHet/sPFyoiBBJn8D@hk7@WGj@6HW9Ls4Gpoc7mkLHDRNT2OR4I8ZW1wK9YUnMq/P2oU2KeQfipx2Xxl42t@6MZngobEaum6bVzTHNsvrPVarjqr1eNyJxNhmOJp7/WI4D7ZmKzkIPT8jfOzMBuPQaWCsb6NZ4@Ux1ZMoVpDB/UJw7V0njX5iW02dflDIMhDYQwlA4X9Jw7sHw/BQ35Lj2kpZIeb/nsidOdEguL9hrqFsjyyTTNsc3z@aMx7g5J3hiYfjIgQcRlEd4l@9@KATpaDlFHt0u689PIN8yvkPLO3QmbsdAZ2hWJKoW@LkaO8EmYzy44aBZlLOoltZxLOhe4LCWdpmOY0/GkjuxbxwVCjeOChU2LRUizYAlvrr7@Fky2hpoU/ZtUqgByt/Es2Zz18oNA1camWmDILaajy7GDnSJ@9wc0gHtCL4lzTbabOoQu77vLNN3ns5gAHlvhQmY/2R43@jgsuGteT9xHju2A6PRCBjl8MDgR/sXNnosT4jJHuHhdaBP99ZsDgnsikGISxv6yGhD/Vpz1/uMRRzwfX2srxiKaG6Q9L/QdWtbMa224b6iSb@Ie5VKu4jQQ2NKusXqBsP7oDTudLhIjPNxC31kYcXGGzmOze/EbTPwUB/fzFVgKKDb@y@Uy7jffmFeYKl@tljU/VO@S8ToctsTq8rqGm3H4vcb9iTZJt8ToLum4SmP0JQB@RVyTALpy7uRhxRv5CFz1Qgk2VPdo0X65arGHKQ6/YAtQAPd7Ti4EuY7btidE7E/cAubDrfw840DbSD8FDiW3pn4RhZvQ8satod0W6kwRGrzwGjj4Z82Ge0Y69PrlclnhnyLBZEdXeE5/4BdYacusMRT0EaStw9bC3rUIlXNEd2IU69cLqfNOpJtGp03Os6aOUSv@dz0QjiUWXlCzhVz1ZFuRLPIik4H2pf2pMWtayDQWIY0Hrig8yvjm6a3A2sqS9ZDJkMDF5kXV2FWiq6ON6DCOsvX00Pm6hqSb9IPeElo3o/Lh9L2SskTwcP//r1PFBiEW4VcYGEEWNftK/iA/MS1/cf7tMCnjjfumdN9wBtPAaxiJ1isPCSBB@8Z6NpYVQioPXti8dmHfmTf1bBL6phE1mslySJ2PTYkwz6VyN7b9HqJHH62S9lGq6djoyv55g5wpUF6FBzzCqP5zyULqFHeiJs9VYUTdlrI@ds/lxH3LOAMIG85Y2nk0VMZeU/3Hu0fySNPXTo@bQ/wdMQ1OW7BfoJWykSmpF7pbmS9k29H65reWLl3qEo7j/ZkjLCC3nxFQ4IHrswtPFbOe/pmRXVFX6kFYagxXi4gPjx6/Cg1P4nJEjsD1xkayWjwzuFhGk@afHK4NDia@gH0jp4zXZl8b1dVk0ua7zObVgdXcc8lOa2CdGSANgqN8SE3v3KrcNVxRkb3aDYyPoPBEzm4957ZF1YW8ol@avaxF7LySkJRR2VluZBLRnZmg7JtuOFzVX2emCPklh16KPyxcjsKSg5Zxc0ulx5uWvG/KsWwjL8T4cMSqZnrrXVsStAz@gN0Kbr390VMVdVVdD7Ue1CvLL@yshYjLFsftpzT91hKNnzlRQq9pDG0Ksm8dR95URoC61bwhtPzvic42yu3wdwEIPQuLO3wZ4Y9022J1rJuEi8qkBo3td0Y5QvjPRakwh0@p2joeekaX7ilniU65EzekvGRG0mys3Nv77YEBz4tb4718ZNn7Knuoa2RmyNGMTbeA@O5ZPRKwnkrNHS3cjm16wIo7UZ4/dHy/lxhh7rbdezZ9PZFODpqikM72RAOYeEbRTIsc2ouG6s6fF7r6fJtRrflzQ9xOLMFOThqg8YH9O5b/0JVMxmyMIRPNcNfb6mZoIOzBLr0GZqtiwYd7YWsoYNyiwweyaXa6CNjittR@GzwMqV@6fhWuGHsKyZXDyc3hZVuCMvdkN@1MPRkWTmj3gAwf0MYy8th8CPHOhs48o7uGt6S/cdLEbqpIOUbClKOcOc3pQxOgtLCou9eLeLj0QX/sbS1HhljNzcaOG0zt7QM2z20Jckeo0306@H@dgrdpe0tfcc/8sHfl@d3NjGWZvRYf7M8gDjNydIgYILGYEJHIq4HLy6QtkHmNey@yc0osnvOeJfeliL51MEd60uzvG@O7k9GqxEFlohW/K9y8YWIz0FVds48dg9PxM2l8yUqP26LW@6/SpRl4XwgGhF9eLQdNKr9Q0WL5DjH4vOnC954ZnS8fxjxc43pdJWuK01XqY5LQ@a5PjnKLWS7WX9xuoRYq48ZgZQBbDh8rhR/OI/75PA6J0CtbTAeWkHIJ7o9nyhdqLCuM6YDhksDR7Mp7Z68FsbPLh5M7Kh5ay/tGyjhZ335CUtPDmyQJxJ2KpVMLn5BI3pcFI3AJtbRCOI6HQ2FuBcXbM0/jgkBYnDA0z@AirbSQD008ASpQCDGtXXIplZT82W2hZ@tqIDwl6Qc0YssUgV5Ndj6uX@2slJRL9lajYkVkfmnW0MDs9xIKsBF845QJiadqGx9DCHrwclMRvb@2QUjhRIkWDWfgTdZiZ5Rr/pnVwGl9fOne093D4@2j54dNjLNS/9sa1AI24bcghP0H2W7IpTdJxsMVNxkMp2ptiA7@hYBKqJeUC4GJbtStNpC0eaFErcwzfq5bSsKHe9VpEvATxJ5bhQKUid6cdhBial@/JPdFX7Slg4MQxVx0CLlCXVWYZllGY90YLrrth9@9fsqFIrf36ngF3gwY9/KLTTEvuN0/Rw9g91@BTk@2N579OxglwUIzhvNmdkdD2rlPDeCzE0OQD31TNrvVGNxP0kc6qpWiz@IA2HicpxV6EA2GSCGdg7RAurgUW4/9QZLrBN8oGA8rBTlv3xduYzLuHU3CXHjAVJxyBaaPDWUtbU1dgSNhN0/2Pts94Ah/rv3yRtJhCDYEZ4G/bMfd7kJ/8AoS/DtIXdIrJKMXwjRE@HBMen5SW6kOXXd0eovEJHJfDovHdrqDz82Igj0KQdot2dkT@2Kra0kmb/hX0zyTaEFGVETCsx@4ywxmjVzPXZqeiae1kYcemhlbLGx48YSsqwns238vBJ@xEmn70kA6hN7zC35@HY/YtDS5JDlpNk6Icu/PiFGIsY316Cxtw0YPJlng@ptjCvsFbREnImt8NP8klSPX0sSgK6QS0LOG4l4zSyZpxy7yrtf@2dKv8rAPQb3t333NHMP3n7Ff@uB@1e5@4WCDe26GbM5LlGE0PSgXwKOSEh/pH3kq1I2t6AwJxxaWwv4KjOHUE2nRHWMznPgdwnY8RxOovEZVBo0N6gx33ICz89wmwm0fVhRFGxSKNDJtG/dmPJNZFdsIBbyhZyqAJLSaQCQjJb38XQsB5hMVqCbCKfmqPYSpIXNzU0molZn1ApVXrPKuv0iK74MEV2HuMLZAJFrMEgDSeYpIKzuJ4PBJ6UmMSlyr7gaR8bVdWBUonAcvfDd9gkhsgQQi9PIQCvYU/wA2didBbY82/jJrsgHLdZ9QJIKYxK5kqLg2xx44oyh@UAnnX@yhtscwE2UfAREI3ke//wemdDE9ihf71nzo7LBlzP8viYjD@Cgspmrg2m0bsXnCOIQQVTEZc238YIdj4/tpsLbJoNm@oMljdkG9y8r/RVtlpd7@7oBxcRV84dILHb30HZQfX0AhWEJTdGyilpIzouUyy0tkl8iPxsoDppvuYDsgE0By@gY5itn5G3v7O59sv/08JqRQIoZvxoN@H59M3UsyelGM3TEo8VarJJ7D5TDx/ceBBUxR7oQ4cbA@P2SqDeVZD4rhSDnpxyuFm0ZhldLtxrj5/wc9FV8s9pNqFGia3iomQ/Il3YaSw/ovNDVzLXSMmrl8zehNIenREDv8MOe11BNJM8vG83N@rEdi19vCUs6wouYvIGdAFzH3sa6go39euGwYOGHMY/wy1letC9ml/dFcT2LtqrwrPnYOZlb6fI9IgGR8gbZAIsUZCWIurL37XMZfW5LTuMf7uRWraI2eyIIFzI3UTwC6ij4BihykbklTN8I5AD0H8tsC4GtJG4MMrBZF9qB5HaOEknB/54CzzjhfxV0WpnKtK0okURuR7DS7Ca7kgG8pAAdGqW7pxPQu546I25fm5aP7xuB68AB9gtaMemdBvtkMoR4PXocGDSVD5xbgsRAyXiIKpelgEv4ZiWnKTTcCfk10LikX3B52M0npkl5YEy7Zh94eyKZBo72kao2WWh6EgtNpibtuEh1Nq@FG7vix3iEN0r2D7I/Op0joDd0GfRaY5qIn8WTlSbkj/7xs@en8aS4rC2RHVTfMGj3qkHUEP2iejMn0cd@7wysjS7jFuXydS4BflcBc4tdwcd9ymV54An0sbYaSu6HY/cROEGMSPSG@oglJja3diYzek0cJ@w0mYGS6txgos1SKVKo4EEBMqOUPXLx8Tuh2zOWUGrQCNDXs7v4eGOOWEOV5Sa4KZMkW8ePbu2AxIVm/pIC6MCQpEJga9iEQM0AjHgnkXkDhzQYDnHhQTbjlgTTN4hoxtNBmlCpWf0Oi3xEbVFyFMvlil@hi1yxzKD1XWeHsgJgr/G5QK4H6vqGUIBmoP7KQmzOyK9zvBjlG@OIPPQtqAA6sYiR08CwCgNYcxOknYGLv8SuDX0F5INK5dnRg1YpqYgstMTSd80uzshzO92hiud/WQW6qbIQNV7lGt3HmAxt3rW4qRc0vfaAOox4haXGomS4@q3jedtU1RtbvZ/QrwWImcMBwD@x1grAoXHHYG/EkrDlzP5nP8OvKYuJdVU9abmnqXg@U4WbWs2zPPto/ViS1huZ2t11HbSo8evpMejkykbu/qkx6LX3@sqxKLIsyynKxvl5/MHGU/OFVng9vcyqpdcnI7XQkF9Pm2Kplj5psqdPP3/bepsUp6ez1@JxQqOv/e7sX4hqDhX9WKXMzrcK2dhJGT@cyXQ9f8KmoLeyE/YGrpMew39yv@lG3Dq627039MGhuMhix8f4lWSxKCpKI96Ef1L3X8LFFf9GXa7LW823b5MNXR9PZ8w0zZHX7cLPGYAEqSUPGeR7Bzg9xVfYMT1JgaJrOO3N5xH0PNzqGh5flO@20IfMJ063jX5/sqvPzMmD8eMvngfXM7zeHCyZkGimUglJalz1rrT0fIxpGe3PfrJ2mT5/2tr8s28MFWMNH/v4@PblY3QfqvmP1tY@uncvl0trmsbdT794@rXt7e3c/XT@aSO/lZMya5t/@idra5q2qSlrTc9Tm/HGycnnopbJifKf/Sjeevr0q55Xz/6fX39bV/FWhNspKwKfgCvLVHDivQQ/FWWs971ib2LQytXYjP5ascD/fI2p9a3if/3u/uvYOFbXlOcuPMex17FCKcad4IC3bPB2GqvHNjFa4TI2U2q1GjiL//XfQfr6JwAHQ2abcKvnA1iFWawu1SjJRaxeAIeqaZDv//31r0cw5GyiRmJccN1lDbjEXFETt5pwbdC1KaCFOymjKEE8ezwYGw5TS3fUO/hiwgs8bAMtghvj4xh@hpbt32XsoJFKpZpyS4JLfoFzRIqqaseqege4gfTRRq0mbTBuwi@bzd9Ba8NJmtHqOzBgGnfY83@MK7bMs/qBQA6EWGHt7sv79ToUJVvPbtRTdPn9h7pSsSQ6zl2RpdnLOCgejebLR7y/sLqYKWliOp3mnWiKBJKm8/ZDn6uP8Sv0wY7KrvotJIEovm/sw@PFdvH68//tz7/359@lv@/R7z@i4T@7a/aUDYh0Ch2hDtfdSqVTr4t1Vzw/xvc6tJ5MpVQpKa3L48QG8J3mAVMzH1/E89n4IaMOpDJ2nKTUcFG2dT97fK/H5t517lOP@vkBPDJ5ML8U5FigGrlDql2LBwOqv0VSapzWmxKKQTWpoRbyTYmnCrCsl1njLlSTqBXLYrOu5bV9qDpV5BU3WPeYEwN9sBDQ0ce3Pi9bPQyZv9WjXrF6kKw@j/Oh8QJ060Ks0VCaBg0DgR@7u1ZZK1UKFU1phZ7XL1a97mUYxlMvdhoLL06d2JygsbBpXvULqiJ8YUELZh8ST4hJBvsHvgD6Flxr8Ef/cIWveF8jH9@boly/1lhF3dCySv6jwq72gfkLMDywTrvdftNp4@ivt/WOro71iT7VZ/q4PWlP2@POBK32vH@ZhNjbxho74GyoyVLBdZy69Xomyy3fSQ4Hf5LkTGNC7B/hqquayjZgWMrADWQxcoKqjH@qKrDYOVzNtxuNtxvQQ@upTWKPzbrkYwkPuXW3mZIuLxvgrlb9/8166KzSxV1QuOZlKrX5og4Sx4t6IwUgX/ggZQ5TbtWbmxQQ5uVn5gdvNkFkkVKbjc2as0M/SAKX1ASAmwtIxnNOvODcvZuS4f0upK@vN1kylVqXpDUcDxv@SAEpmvVUUCTEIAESwvn5z/kD5Q467OXmZf2ysXl5ubkJ/5t0v/Sf4Hu5ee2fHvNrRZx5eBMZy3FDqR8rxz6baMK7rNTRR1aOwVGHJ8RrZLVSs4EOuOTmf5v/cnp@D30Q5aYMWAuxDbYRQyN02diGEHv57sv/BX/H7778fZQRGfwZFSF2jn1a2UANs8wVTbgx@7HNHvPLBjf@glf0QY/HdfS0@c3GRShFeSmzCp/nT6ilQlLG4bfl9Fp4rl1mLyEqCmswKjFRKxXEVkqdaSy2KRaKNC794rUrHo//k5dauRjnUzJ4HPul53mPI7iF2LHHELuqZVRJvahzk@P8IxC/uOz6J7@46hJiF2VmVIAsHY9xgggxaD8xSYJBqr45xP26uCgiof55WvtcerYt4YSJPqYlrw6fDKjt7dbK5Tpfz1l/Sn1l4/4G3FX4312DYgix9mv8e/QG/9hRB/8OXuMfO3qDfwdj/GOP2/h39Br/ttv4dzTEv3uv8e/xGP@e9fHv@BeyWbUqrp8TAVJqWb1cn4pEiGpsq378C7x2evGffucb34jXanEpTl@fyKmOy9RkFUjoefHq3bgQq7F1dV3NWJlORm2rbXCYLOOyzCAzULsgE7VUljFYZpaZsczQUbvgMuAvAy4z02OZPsvYGRsiQii4xq3MGF09ePThrweAXPgzcQ9ZW810GGRkofJBn61D8OC6aB0LDRZn4ksDNENZlTNywWzixz4a4suXx8pGUyuXmIwNQ241Xh7Hm2gWWivnWHtmrB2/ZDEPVMtqTDk@VvgkGZSVyHF52WrtPrnfaik4Uhw/dvbn//v7w@jrjf/DfefxvjN04H9/fx8auFFP3U1Jd@GqAW/1H1uxenXruEKsOWDPMWVz67ieldBdSAHL1dAv9YHXHCI862vHQvwsgVrBGSoG1edn1dMquc@CV3C0qvMIQTTu8J9wncEoFKgMZ3CdnqGD3tB59vw4dHGH8vwMvJ4zUInCf1C9oq//AP/mf1v/j5@xJEs0msnE@eVmgq4k/iWT55fnl/69nkwk/JfEJvyhB7xjkvPLOjop0jm4GolkM3l5yf3gnkhucoB1yGazTmnn8YB5x8IsKVt@S/zDPiFr/zqOV5k@395yfDzNZJLVdmDNHhdr9QvaQ5Cs0hfL1tsNtfmnP6IvFmwlKVI@V62qG4y/aDmtWs0Fb8VStVoKXtYTifL1q57ZUgugEORyyWS1Ci9bAdgMvIZgSwA2eMkDVMPTOz4XPN/bJ1v@wCXyMfyIBmcLiQx9CQQ/KhUXK@KdOwn/Y9Vb28k7d7Ry5uIi9BmNwEtd8Gq1uqbbaqF/9uJCbIm026Sch/dM6eJCzZRTajzpuIkn@DUyyCohqewjrU65loH5arli8h9GRwBg@c3NQq5eL@TAXSjhuvf1i6jBxPV47DwYsotJzhrj64pY5Son9G4PL3Z@GaNqZ7l8MgHMNQnC22UM/7i3Wi5z/yTLFRKlVNn/q62B5gyiCP9DeSqbym0UN@6CXIp/06UX8uTquVFTL2vnRgXnuy@rHf9bsHiG3rhzJ1sGspYy1WOh1bq/fbTdatVEUURxBm7oSdxdwE/Qjdx4g6o8X242sITNSvUutQ21lGfQCPxIUhzGCFaCqlK0jbxaQmoIZg@NZAAFBK7TrLE1QaMn3oQyp@YaeILOgdnjrwsX67I26@PF@jh7yUxm0cUsxsPp3umEkRx@@aHhK6XFK/QxwkuIPX20vbN7lNY2JRbTHmzvpLXDZ/diKr7m5@8UnMX3g93t@/vPIMHTR7vbh7sf7322@@wp@HvsbH4FvN6/z59R15L3M/ZceOW@0Q1DNyaG0TqbTM5es1em2TKhDq0JFMLpu8wzWoD7SJ@Xowq/junpr17p7ogu9u4H33r3g//u3Q@/8@6H33r3w@/99MvvfQt@P4bfd/jzO/@2nMf7T7/8F7/77nd@CJ7/EX5/BL@f/PTL3/w6/9H7H8PvP0f8/tj/ReLxnwCwfuWnX373Rz/98le/D79/5f@@f/33az9Z/vveN1f/MN13f/fmON/5d/D7PQ4riPud3@F@@LwW/3d4vF/9/rvf@Pf8/0/9P3T@8N1v/DHe/Jd//v0//c/vvvEfNK30p//m3Te/@@6b33j3zW@/@@Y/1d795r9RM9Hb77773h/81R/@3l/94f9I/z@m@@@9z/@77//zv/hf/@J//4s/9H8/gd@/B9dP/uI/QN/42z/4Af5/9w/@9o9@gP//87/@2z/49b/9lf@JHL/FHf/Pv/q3/P7Xv/af/ua3v/1XP/n63/z6T/7mt/7gr/6PX/2/fvM//fV///t//c@@gZ6/9ZO/@qNf@ctvfOsvv/kv//IbX664f@vG@5fv4f/lP4LP@@P5PnDep1wf6vPlz4XP34ca81ygnUDr/uV3v/lL0MB/g7F33/oxHjqB34r/H2sqxfkxf/v/gEO7XmYMyYALfr/@7lvfQRL9D0Ai@A/p9e3wZSGEv3x7/gJk/e0liX75p1/@yx/RW8yo1GkZBYfsklZKbYBas1Eu@8O2v8ICSX5pEVoIwM/p28ihFsK@jbzt3Q@@/u5H//TdD37r3Q9@BQdMKVdOb6cl9dapQin/HvEwYuF94mHEzzH/FE2CSanP4Y197gd@/vnnQutCwdNNdy/A93Py4hfjQXj6yQ8KwtAfj0OxCxZ1@86M71z3fcOcGWu8fNnEBVDww9xTJHBsBBJRPsumKR@xKeNLLugPkaYb5JzinXwxeCrgbf4/d04FlsI4/MKvsQVOcvjp/Cy4U8hDNqlpuNBDIhrjItEG96GFW8o3V2ZYguk0NQXdFxyQQwqC7qVYrVZLYcIaxwdeOWr1EiNUUqkalBtT8zTpVglBTO8RFEhZSx2w1kZtyhOmEF49IEdKQK8DUdXEVKl2HzKsTe8zhIXACezLl7V6qTatI7i3nB6paeoe4YTAaqlp/S281wgmpBNi998CKqVaKlUvYYZYSF496RavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCJ@@@37jL2kaiWxBaXEpFgPDbeU/PYGBGiQ/hxasMvDv0HTvptEMHXKCs/F8bDt0gg3eIyKkYAuJIkyzKDH66Ib7G7EDzloFKULTxSHEKKWgS1gNCD4RRQSkhR/aboBfKP1TY@@EJgWJj19XUhVhez4r5MpFMU5p5U6DAC7s9DJaTCxEJZRG@DTmYEuED6KuW/Hsc1rzjjgNlHKf67e3eDfQTFpOfcT2BSKuvknBiHsplKiRrArzsp4QVoIwK0UwJ0IcjTGik8KSGdZkyuxTCM7e/v@0iQx4uakIJmrmVVfMeVnslkEoMUspyW02n/KdOTPGTfIVOo/5TXkbj0ZV@mabkqKE1Vhl4squGooAyj59u3b6FWaMNTZQ/0VObvfdJyJQoED27kwbJmwQkeLVcWuI7O1EKOsQRNhMKVZEmBJdhGUuDb5DkSwZWIa6VSnOIB9eXERrAVrqBSc8BJ0FgdEQ0urjiW8skgcGef7ew/frz75GjUbDLBoC8VG62R63QMz0tg2PaT@/yIhFYuJGONBoI@qmjIYITdSoaY8d79g73DCuOF9qsgQYhVacnTL2ZZFWKj0fPNmL8VSMSvcDniId4r87IltHIWksbqQqxjoGaBa9lV2gJSFR57/XvOFNT/tCim1QKqc0ma@mXC15wJQxuR3KAE9Ck8OCFvbhIFhPq5ROsK6ITaKgj1ur@JjqlC/XD3CBIc7TNVy8hC/XM2lTFD6VKoWzXLsPvjwTruRhOPM2KkTOuNTBr/tGwW7mqukFbzxebamnUuYZ7HVG3nuK3wEl7PJSzGV@BiwlcE9hXwggvywL2CzN@oubdf9XfLoTWmBN8yJ6p56GZJ4RgqmoMTRvMLEIXWvbhKI8TWvvhizOp1UKulvQdCDLjFgAUbxiSzKw9kqubuxDUotM9Y1/zMxM@ryV3TG1n6DLoOUCN2eXnZA0h7D5hW1@iVp@ji/bJDPm1wX051IWZXKrW3aq4oaCeVytuspgngIWwouCNtDRoALfFvKPyv6kEm2WxJAU6liiI8stmsgNPDglAxBEa7N95majWJt8FsTqXNGzhNoOjTmhZeftzpR/O42QyPiyEQwPpjl2WCsCIP898KAr0B0XC7Gn0ftup3zsydO1mcu8jmMuEkBZWYXULdrGdzWaS48P9fixctv2yO6tmMuqmMwKmDM7ep6OBsgzO/qbTBaYKzvKmY4JzUs2pmU5nUBSZscsOMDO0@1MSxMUU7sNxPrHuG1ZPx1E9NpAw0cdM3dFwPEta7ta7ToY85V7uyiR/VxuOaPEEuJ1YdG02G1dB4AB1wZYnkudCvndGhUsGo9WW0QuHauiV05bbTncneeGbh@RnLcWtxkAvjQcAcugECCc59bWWzuUqDNeWRM9oStHwx1VAzMJLgTy2ltfSasVUsVrpyxzJ0dytfyZfSXTya469JbeUzlb78@eNHD8fj0YFB53W2cmVIgHab0MLKVqmSzzcbDVFMNSibJn6jlvMpaW0NOrehdyV49hx77ElaqQmJu6Zbq8XjW1lVk9RKNlO6FOaEQ5pjCesCJk1hydJI93OfFVRsxwauU0nrafOcqFDp9XqXG@ep@Yugn0v8DehzKenp9nn4WpUi8SpskpbMeSD46D0g97m/GFcRtXxJrDaq8/diQaw2L4W7Q6Nr6nhM5zhzfj1VAbgzhxqDjI6ZcFlxHWdcaRs9xzXmEbNqIYjIEboeISdehtkdZzDH8@vZFSKRpufXoeTy4mWYKkBLuLwEunNiQ7/gRjfrtJu1oZZzzV1gRY3mZmCOE@sm9uKFrtfrUMnnuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1GHLKuUK@BN0sU8jkNQ0A5MqlcvESWrQQ03WpXstqWUHTJC0rZVVJzeL/LQ4N/98/vgb/Gt4hVVYTjtCmxRMYy2D8tdkjPBs/dtiRg19H6bN7RmdFjJ2BTvt@d1zH8/4ece7p9gkPum9yQ5Jh0EMdPxHlDc3xYEWMZ6MhmsMw3H80CLvDNiCIrIlHuAc313KcZRGK7NnTFaV8HJpuBmJw280Q/WDv44dHkefR7vbOQ6HA7u0/uX/lkfcj5dmj3QdH4WuRhwZJ8yGIr@0@enT11X/k9p8d9CaOiz/hwf6z3PwWeuGxUiEH12Kk0JuA@Dd8JWkPJ/rXWL4YOFQBDyPcAY31ju/MF@bODDqf8zOzphdujufHpyvCUXCQVmfI9doG63CrJ6hCk0UyX8BWi2VBGDHbOWPFDOs6lqXj9657a@A50PFQoIFSpkWfa8eszxzX6p6ZXWNNeIznD8sqflsYkRAeApDhpEPmf0DCQPuWXfwSNS4rta2JwSb4FfgVnvBAL3S6Zn8A4@GZE0QQ2rrO4PehF6Q3otf4Zo8xz4P8roVY16MLMUEUH@pj/W6s1Kh6zVE9U6ncuaM@dcVyVvT6xu4U2it7Bv1Hd2fpkjiWxQdMbsX6uNJgFdR8zhnV9TqoBg0QpGEU3cppRr2Uyf/1b//47/7k18tav6ZuHGd2Mo8f5SvAGkGyZCQ8@gKmTKqGVi7lS@WsVkqXyqVcXi3k82lVS4OWViyDoJ5RS2qhlC@r6VKuDAJBrgyh@XLRF0@VQB5VNioA1u7gp243SVuRB6CW8FVE9iahJ1lMD98nTDQgjSigYjim89UbZg3GMqZmWLbIAKLOOiz24MFO5sEDUbyHL7h7Yicjil18yZcymeI9UTQoZKeEwo3o8DQlNBomjvlLJnNvRxQnHADa2xbFAb7sFnCKSxRNfNnZfvAA8@nhi4bpIdoJD@EvVvBShGg2voDUTABeh9Ag2jbPJ0eI7uILZokhD3jIDoSJ4scBOhhywKNxAA@Dkm5vi@Ief9nexpAdKnaeI/opvmzTJYouvEDLF8U@OPou9DlRbIMT278odsDVmengh58VRpPM9lgXxRknDxJIFKcUW@@ciGIr8MdsPvOxySN1K/Si8lLfpZcy/omiFiCN0bLhS1YUc@FLDsr28OFn@mDcNfr8mrn82YGSPnyY1c3pZPdB@@OP2/1@251t7358gEE7Ow9BMJhN3Ha/7Sdst@ByINXOQ00/Gc6uXlDqvVaroltLgz5ttXK6fSWoNWsZiCGkeg2Y@VcfMxq2diBo52Hrrr5sRZcAtrDrD@HZxuveEJ739DYPCi4Koue03Rar2PxRasdFWOyJJ8BF7fRQ77hOFd@ntTXG4ol4etYoZJpVCmBDkL4z1UsM7yXwruNUTPJ81pjWMs3atFbU@G6gXkI8nmp5U0yvDbfUcr6ypm@pWi41raB1B6cXZ3FJ3WIJ9c7GG5Z4ktzSQBIXj7e2JLGhNrc0tVQpFF9sTEQxWcH7VrZYgYiZeIYxvCUbxeZWMR9JUiymdEWrFIvJ6iXQYwxjeRunSFqJxJmhnySTiC4q7FAEKiubUTnNai8xTU9rHC82S1anNbXKrZCyzDVYXTR5PemMHZdD7AO46VamgsvgCVEtl0TIX1ESySRq0qQqK8J8s@Tzrx6dHB19DpyQCXV/IuEp/0J31X/9@OGOvLcfvKGpavkBaj@OK@8gu1oI4ZaUA68j0APkhzB4gk4V@OEZOtex5N1pxxihChUEBAZIZd9spHz0cAHO4cA54zmjCYIq2R6zOwZDS95ml@m1Orj0LksQVkxPntGw3arXa63akE7pQxGDVJ8yMnM9B7PncdxDwwiU/BzPlfkBrVrmstquTWNTgNOqMUl9OXS6L7VUp9pFA973avcwcbUFz3bVqBmu67hiTKz2tuwaYxPb03vGU8NFkx97@@sgROBhs0SPGcl1dryLsXdQW7iU6i6z55g9mQwTII63k4tekVckTeKrQZHP6fQj7pK4rPZqLPEiWX0Nr@46S3Tle8mtXLWbuMdaSfDJvOy97DGNFXJV@rJuAiFBJyLaYJn1ZK3@Kcg9HPBJpQKI@HV8AjAxJwBrdilAT47My2qnZrGExKYsSeTJVfu1Bqa@wNumJIpNSWpcNIW6JD0X6tBPq7OYXvMmbfrqA8u0VS1TqE7BTy3mqgOoWP3FtOrWRhPXqFrw6s@q8UOeehXICVQDMG8uEu9@6evJTSlf435VAnVhgajRklu1adVGO3LQJGrZGgSkGrlMGjRouBXTMMxrhbRaSGfTubRURF8Y49P5NHiCVgMSRcJKiIyJ6cw0I6tp1VDTicxLs/symT5JgKhCJGPJ9NjZtSdDBj5QSdgq6RWeOkumtA2LQS04TN@UqJkCp6hiwYDmAzYy0wMEdWDoFqVIJiWW3UhY6wmMs340Ge02mpXK7nT0VQhKSK@3CqliJvUmmawm1pI1z3gt1KtCHbkKlXq0Bm3Wn3Bk3mTYgDoGl1rUKo1GG4tYzKSzmSyUzmxd9DfFuthMZ9YKKlTRJSPxiHGOEZ2DQyFn7jdqobRtGVB1almrCjJNiGVLmlRW8hv5DJ@U4ymFkc/WkJIscSwGB5oT8XhRi8eT8SouB6yJ/vwv8DLiY3FgqvE76pYI8pdYEcsaRpizRDqzmgmwAwnsUsDJB5YrC7Fz4fL8chNUYYU2UIK8yNbIJcn1u0KswhiIgce@CSVljbEP3ZeZ2qy/4M9j3DYPcAUy@AoCKO2XMkxUv9hneDx/i8UBMd0dNjQt22xoRRjIgDkGUUEJr@IKSAz35ct1oLB3Dvhtpup4su1TNpvpKSmYkr/DWD@1LlCZY1dXO7dr2/2D7WA32PYOzvIeg3wtVuNi7Dwei1/CnxC7S8fpNH6cjsUiB@r4LP8vxO/G4vE4TqcDod7GiEewnfNg9quC3x9L6BXOERrN5NsnpnVeykp8UgJY1OVlbF3BtU5/mSKbKyTLVFPBAadPX2rQSGK2E3iAXoTzRzB45fM4dR1TXo68L7RS9vHevn3ffWAwft6plGuJ9RjLqBIeG6pWfN@82Fo7UaGNZMXsSTrG7sZo@7lYLmmixj2qMXYixdUKPyM1Oiy/KL4ovXj8bP/Z/gMhdrx2sebgKgULd9O9tT/5KkSMZ3Nxxo5rsWktV/X30tXrkrqpoRWzIqsA@@@pBSlzUefNvE4BBQ1C3v3S93PTzRK8axkV3jUtn9LqdXVDY8nY6N2Xv48Gac53P9t@xOI4t/13f/Ijrfh3f/KvaaNe/JLmu7VsMQYx0akWirHz89H5@SVcPCwfa8Y4UrliEtx87UWN1RVVy9q2XWUVRdc3iqmcdteuKn5ctagmY54U81eRivmYd@EHaZkSBAXLPOQlFrBKYrsHZl5T725uQXG2sjmtugbNSA1PZbLwb9PwyjEhVnr88oIxeOnUu/2@qZFLUVjlrcQ230qb7C0usbyV1tjLWh2X6lU8yxksQWzgKTdchovXU8pGnIFaxOqNy@plM0WrGKA9vjCMDfv4Sic4XsODDoteGzb8GRse/WGiwMOD1@DN2HjliYmNpKJ0u6HVs02D5evQKjYUwG0jWIfgf5J0nHz3S7@paYW/@5Nfu2hdtD7XQJEslwuqFvvZzzYn9sQzuvWfQcIbLI0EyiAt4qBJEHSESiTjli5NP1XokDugv05slJp5/EClRCUSZQ6zbxtdUimFU5STqCJb3NhdN0HRNtAQQZqkbjIulawKQiidklTt9jtpgsE20BQi9HThXPgKBsFgzGrAhIWvzEGBxxCGX6fT8qyJO6JjIQlKpzbT7A4kgRy@gnYE18iAgs/JJeB@ysb1pBxlj6hGMhUbGp6HVglhEBK@Akl8M7HWjI10tPWBMU0bhg4ZoxCeFNBtQN5NyNviCVrkm6DS8whpxrHjiWyQvIWvgDBBVDBBxmDmJkSoAlv6ChAAypDwAZtNtsmySXZuplLVucnDS9waj0YZ9cDOgIDJEFoX7VoEiasYD7xA4scPE2K78GsYxLuIZwCEw@BL6jXQGTA5vaHQRoZA3hsUwCKjWwkqGrtzZ45VrWZ2k4xKhPBPzBHOdVE92MtxBWCBvvVRtyKmGRqTrAa@YbMDiqcIXWh1ErciWY0kZSK@XgoC/L93o8UWeaWqKKCKBfDri/eKDpAMEiPZeR122GaNqVoxyULkO4B7h5Ci496hEnk8/UjWPg8CLwHDn8WCz34AizqKzh/67faqoQkGg@gEv7mA5sY4M/ANRHCDYsjq9sZB6jAVFMW0KHbPdEHBobX@wJZhIqsmMdnc9iPhQRvetRxuFdfySXxQKozN4KmjTT4/nzWyJdRxoEK9kWOTET8yMoR7@qFFAI/y7Z9xtCf2GX6jx68bShzFyCPbZ9jyEWMySkgfN6a0uNjedkELDmiTZkZfZp1hl2lllqCGRnba7BBckhIRwm2QlpHGbcsYAkqHhkHHtLyKovRB2Jq0yVjdYxPa1eCBCeON7Sn@d6SVM/PEVI7wGwOS08PTXNz0RwzlM@x@fF3fNwxnOc4Js8wTg08LJxYMp3gM9AUQedNA2fkPCFvBDSNaNs0yEJzmseBXhEeRO0vpSNq1xCx5/ZlV1xItrNELGnxMF78RfarbEfrSdSH4KrI38wLTS2RACN7lkOUavtGVWhzNKYTWhATfiFSN7BfJuNwwSoDCGhhfQqcwco1ThsqugGMMMM1OYMYEezGU9is0AFDfg56FNhnHbgWN7wAmbjfRga7nM3ibfcSymoARuWUs34oVwMCqry1ChzBIiuXwxl2oGJnm2JGvQO8cdiEMzT74zQ/TB60b3WQvc9682ZoPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wd2J6p6GsQWAAMl2CylhBTADYlJkUOOkx/NTlv7QLxkgq7DinNEIJPaoBCokLwEXkW@ZiOAAH3dI9bXPctNp6dnclkRnTimrLh4QdmPMfWLWXUN0GidpSxMRz5n/I08RPOPty5S@LflZJHg9HWFEXXWvnOjD8FoefV/G03iXjPi@PgeIrfT@kPyeQY2vryqEE9MOnbS52EvwuItz@tmT4P2l8F259Uil8iEMYQzDQ9S3fSACzd7pyke2fdqh9wSh0SgEMtGoEnGvd1g5ehF7jMUS@M4YyRj4ZBbeuEFlABksindOdZ8xIGMWfBq/8@MqeQyDbO2Lbr6rMEhScxNjbgxIzEHjaDYZ9CwAnDDDvnlmbNaWPWXEg@DZPDoBZuH3DRnphwfjNQbnYYw6c8fArhUx4@nWcaZNuYNrlIhl6XWBxs9WiGMoiJYGZBnEtuonceQpBB@mYqB4ExZwt@l/Dr1Ch1QG/@BvVYCxoGtIkRENxIKI0Xx43jpu0ZZxvNlNKHxi4SIaDGAXSjSTQ964ZupL51ao0cb8HLRuujMCr5eKNXZ@C3Bt5WsIxhBVHD4PQy0WBkf@jvc@ACgV9ggIByGASiaLA9TpjJamjmmgKh4TTEOY05Yg0fmSZJX36Q7wfiEic9J2wUUDMCCP3DIgGaEMKCnsM/JxZwh@euA3GCuBJ9AWmIhsvizThQ8kpX4bymSpUUwUqSAjSB7Ciu1q4WJQiHqmhcCYoU89Kv/yj6ax@Mfg/6xXLsqcHyAaMqRLsK7jEEEcLvLkRVVq9F6hUwUDZ0y3Bh5Nrl8qk/WkM2G0qgZvB8sAjeGX4jPRGp/E6S1w@daRRtsRI2hVmtBkWc1Xi35P0iICkneJjM85PNgobgp@cMBGBkliYz/GTTaLJprcYZB5uuSHYWQXJKSE55Eh57ugLJpp8MtKe9YHjB6mmCdIqbIEWAp/JhFMSgkcjwQ@m4Av4KjSri2qmf55znUCvw2xCK2NjOOs2luTciSEeY1hUA2BCvAejyL5NWhKsMT5XCt5BHcVIGPIq/@c2A8wpoYMSCq9zwcCJsZKQDg8AvpmgcgL4rphqCqNK8MP5l@E9MB57BT73umVmMqS56ZtJX/v5RPJtI2UgHjUgfaiaHDBk1mWe2b7EzKnPE8CPeAwekuvaZwxJLhG3wVyZ@UqVtOW1lqONOFvxeIfeVR7NkoD/gmgq7O3LG@tjJ5SpcaTKp2S3Ln@sMZt928DMnEePjIOt1HcOz42Oo1I7Tt03PSDO0C3li@GqH4X8NQYjKyb7T8QTBn9HkaiyC5u0KRd1WC7@g3GolcNtgshJuhqZdhNg843EB9V9wRdIDe/KB7o8STvuV0Rknb4eJlvT9ZEdm5ySxP/IDcfZ1mwEP64D8D6EDkGCY58w1R7LSjaJ0e5ygb30MnKHTB6lv4skCpr4Cfm8OGxHSRyPCJc10VGkrke8pUC9JdNJ60k/66QcnZZ9qCT0ZptcWASwQI83cqzRGyrpLsmutzI4nC/I7/HB8D6P4Ht6ML2nhV3HmqnmNB35Y1tnEHAJEnKORvR0NLDrwre41dBZQCb1RruIJ3hvFLu0U6yKm2xB1248u96B9pMM3D95CxD9bRf@bKzBIvvu@1afjZ@UPZ8BvhrgDMkFfpvKCxdEERN9LIu@5nl3YtO@/Z14QFz8K@ABFCBBjiXHZaGAYOuYI1G4vnC4OAN/S5nFz1rV2Tzu2ajxwCU7uaZqdaKur6H6ra1j6zOgm/JjpCNygxAegsBG/er@CI6MjpudwXS8BY1cyDIVhHInOI1VWNBk9fZpMrm5WPIoZth6aKScM91bTD8OvsWac4qvx2WrQA@LxGE7Hnpo4/TmajWbchr3Fv0/k81E@/vCaRMMNtxME6MBHTzU9zzZ5E/s8SIRFeo8RIYwrLxYZTUwHENEY0fU6/DAS3V5SqNxIolpQy8Li11uW17h5U41HWkXQJvkq0/s1ydsa3Xu3uUhT48DmLGznw4aQa5BxP0enk4hC5D431phjX@MJ6EfzdPaKUaW1hKGGKYnTjU1St0m@SAqoGe/BEyecPoMnAuwb4xZvUEHZcE7L/9Ifo5ChPopILb4PCOkAJUJFTnIfjUgsIXBD9PPLMM/Oyjw71/LsLOQZ9oDFLCORhM5Cln4tYPXcVAWW0Ruv4M4YhLozPG5i23DZju7ibMV53IxXzDSLn8YrwJDjRryymwCmHO/GK/fJ4cUrh@Q4iVc@Bce8b8Uv4pWgW2AEF17JcRf9fRaO7514ZSeRvBTG@onhBfnK8UpYpxBni78SRYAUWG6QGnGJzXb8Yo5dAwY2EirTDFuMl0b1ieZh0vTLwD//HhN9qQUDcY5zgyKzFFMXBo3IiMHzgWEj@BLAkp5c8Ufz3f0HtB8qjILZpEDHi6Yh8CCGx@KLzIgjhqG0ogFPQBD5ZmU5Riwykr0nOn7u0EKpkhfzJ@rJJA90ExTegMjNeSb0ES4/fVBfiyB4Bb4fnph4FZ7X0AmyI4xwTTa5BC0k6sv4DYXCul7Exa/9aA3RXPdiJMBWCqLwWiKwEZ4OMhwtzmFmI2e02EgoFPfbm9E0NCnHOyW23ivJiCv4PXNFMHn7JUPGEO38yZuKE0mHqC2wIAxsZJq8l4XjAvFiDJrzuoikyjsfoBDhOdDDjc4JfeDsvu@keJzdpGmsWDUMBWl5lsS5FtkkJJbREtZEH/PcQ@V1F@1jfZj6GqSc4lxLAgFEUoa5cP7qfID87nD5PRCoAyJcyWCZYL18KL0uXt84yl7B3Jpne70CMTDN7ieXCkdhDnOSg3YQkcxvamvXRHzc8sGFfJ5pCP2KtB@QLdQJbqHbVd2Cw0IpwT1d9DzRwPNEW02o6xKJdSoHQouMOflweMFDTOdFuxlXXvBlVYwhNL@tWx9cwe5iBUcrD@FRAdwrJOe93J3YtMtl3reBbXMfZKlqhXFGTsulYTXPPYHd09JtuGwLHvutg/v7Tx59DQbdYrGY9Mfo2Rw/7LU41xqO4xwyba4Ox4MlaouWxq8Q4WI3Tsd7A8cdrx3b4jVewpk1CAM65BI0P7@PJ31eFuHnV/oupONxIxT1YZ3Mu4G@wJVQ1NFxyDZ9uo6BIMY4saH7QALxFuidJm0tSd/babVsfWi0WjR8tVq4eanV8kcxrJpgRTz5s9iaMvFc@lIw/1jUmSCQmQd2f589f7h9xI4e7rIHz3Y@ZV/bf8aebz85whP@T5/de7S3w@C3@@RwlwkLuy7xw3qoUAJd7xsd4/8t7lq32liW82/mKdoSNhoY3bDB2ELYAoStEww@XOztBVh7kEYwe@u2NQIk2@x1kh95geR/HiGvknfIrzxFUl9V91wkgfFx1jpey2hmuru6urq6@lYXREtVy4XCM8WQt3r9scidzJYt3w/djnrba3i4ploP3M7rS3nJdb3hhpSq0nZ0jDNMnwMpdvwh9C048h9tY7G4abKNIGwBFOU9pz1tB3veTq/pt3zKa2Hv2/e9wJiVqbZPPUjy1lg5O7JIQpA/Vh3i4J3QwLqh4i7lx90NgXFF/wokRg6JCtjMKU248N8PU/CoevDuUMFZxNb@3nbtqLa/d6h29g/o9f2n2t4bomft8OigtnmMJM74bn@7tlPbqvAHQaCQU/Di8NtVMLwXhRyyM1Uav@PmO9en7g/fkqfeWMGrG5etJQO1cNWF9PHdtv/Fay6UrKsAyxdYaPJVgcrMVw7efKA5X3l/4IbTXAWz/kHqOODAk/MFtc610WDZoPFWsoyLxky2aPN9RGesEHvGK7F3hww/O8oAZyWepu@p1BZ0VHD2LU4geCwb0FTRI4INUEZhpaw4ZtTCgrPOIDeotka7B9@dUpsoEeoXFH1tVE1KFlNM68oAKOwdal2cBxVL4Qfie/qwrKsdDiSDehp@kAzqmXzAUrQG3RG1onNcDfevIJ7Vqnz4rdPf4Wth9Tz8sOnyLnZN4yT9xl3qqjDmHlxitDkymJzycPRSN2j4PhcJOD@iZrXbMjA8iddIMlGuElm3jXKmSNi0cNWg1d4kDDJSiRugJ@S2hoHKlO2cOoJykNf1JSbbRdvtigpUpLrDvKfW4H2ovKGXD2EsM7Yg6feYARFHMYlHWG5brwq9h5ajkptTNbpaR5LjiRoVtO8hsDmFwN8DhgBlEzudBs9UbMAKML2WZuVM0COOxLntn/H8xM7Nq4aXKKC1tjK/@V@@2JrITmKfZPQUGTvqoi/egJaVfJXZ6g1ojLNY5ehPkIKNy15/6EsfZpIt4BsnnuYoNyY2qu1XQ1xdG@gwWWO3141Vek5cfEet58SUD6mVOV7uzkPxFYUFJs6nSVj07oCOe9679mJ3Zw4ukW48HL/QQpjvynH4OR4yJrL@tCLZ8adCNNG18sb25mn2z18dhBQVsSARfY3SIf4TY6IuGh58z8cKiwOsu/RIM6HggqtzlNY6eFpaYpQbYLQPvPRpX/e6XgrTRN14@jtsbCa/88dv38pSKgvJpMNAB5eZSLo56sRU6XCZM6VVQGKyk5AlWZ8xXxyGGcrr17CrQS/AnU4XcgT79olAa1qEmNadX7VIsuh4t7q7Q/i22mCNiihYOOxl4v2R/5zZLC9t2PlIoUTFyJkxItoxkIu2HVNL4flqCtz2/eBIfj8c3Nq92Mn08EPQtu@F9kO4ZZfuhiXTUgzWw8H@eQ9Ymdz@LrDUduduwDJJTkMLOT1kTmc@HWrT3l/jr1N9x2OPwGDuxQlKCDRW21WXr6iNq@yMFLDjYKIF0eHRdvXgQKVkf0JlSe5hy9DUYhCwH6n3kbat32VhlwsXTXH/1rJ4Ml8SGm3m332DeSbx7hAVeg3iaHqEwiKK3NPyRyL19MzCSwjWvmeBaCiXxO6rkUHBiQZ8S3tAQjbqtFgDrZnNTMvk4wdxJXBNN0fWxnEdftawlrkbUWQH4ziguE6QewHLktn991HWxy9NPbLAgushNLhJK2mab2ifcEgV9yljLpfswXu6xXQplOxlgZ02tIPiVyG5wv55hmJGkkW4rIVjYl0vjjVqsj6eN8scVkjENOBC01MnikYzJRgRz1/W4x1qR5NeJjkF0SITcUVfx7mCip/d6imMqRHOk@VwQR4fa/OMzYnB8gynsxp26e5Mj6ELvTopHiarIml7b1XZ/5@qZJZI1GRoPrMxJpEgr66sPP0e7MlWmOLZn4Utc8ik/Bx2@rS/j0AG44CP94lza3uOSY8Y4B7SiWq9GTATBWmpM2NOSbSdJ6M4foSLnAsRMnAaj1Ctk7XaajSB22zoMiPFoXOWqTbEhnDYUBk1U9S/vb86COTv1vfox@uTwYZMUB28hVb@u94g8CKrvJhvl9gnWMMmv3mDQZeziT1TB1AybMZ0r7EdW9uJwqu0Col83xZvSUtbJ4narWPOGrgSPl7MITozTvdKk8d72WIp3tSd2m5VLbITyVbiLDI1SNkx2fPI796HAMtgPpfA9ME2fI@Dl/SfcHAMSCITW/NlmDb2d3FjitCq@YQDB2m1UC1bi5O93woabhcuQZzU40ClnCdUkE9hq/s79qyT9UIpUZ6QC/rdDJVyUtlciovSNxzoAlIShPQmvscmLFhqGE1JmNdc9KAfhYstbySnZ6w56eaLa4XVFxa3rusMnc7JizNnsVFOKZp83W4nuBrcNH@/6F1et1Rb9X87HzXGX/5QauWZekp1LT8RT77F1XKenac@p79r6kWBOVcj@Iq9EiNacE7CqCq1oKJ9eOmRkpAkvGl@CQuJCS5Vix3DhTCxG5Y7J6tn5W65UOqcdM9KMPIbLpWHS8WlDD48oVmUZIzczJ8MzzCnxk9dve61gr9MDtypTUMUm4bQl3fuwO/tVvbeJE7jsADAEZjW9eYDdYnMPAdtNtie5LreTUYfkzkKHGthgWTNsVVQEabyfJ6M45imT5hRrzi0mg1G/HdsW3OF3FV/2OMU4xQRrKW@@d@sOWPGVOATBcpy4hvXibAvIDhRngwuhuTrWLSos0VZrhVhO2nHQJygJIvD1GkqBZtCIKptuU7OrCDnuY1LIIFQ5N@4mFpf58DkxGpBjk/xoMrhDthgonCGR1yA0E@fbxtQBa/cAzb7sKj5eC/iQb7wGdWQ7WRYQd7ilSJSoP6tvrJ9E5dfJwII4edkzZXTR5x65UULSbEd5MMFeDlLbvxxzQCzSumUOTQWsKW@cgScNcWZRqhWk4m@z92AnEIr@qdbkC3y21Qzwvy2ZGeS8D21fgtAS@5STtrATzsqlokVy5piJnOMFHPfpQZOumh79M6jYTVWW167TUgLLeYicuCR7Xt1/Uth/cEJ6jwLkZf07FR6NpGek3RBKsqVowk@yvQynimV/hrlu1WpKJszVVdZ8eIlRz3dyNGSJMpbui9vkBv26n6UeSPsSuHKMGE9kZCNpXye0fuS8ihRJmTwMP1E0jV/L@ueD7FM5H2drB@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@/KHAuXVtFtM3X1td8EAY3FSauH22G@sICbAKEHCnW8IRFl0VZJlPjuWePCa5cODqKIGvBzErubCMnQ7Q39BvUMn2RZbQIl1yBRZd3mBCZUX6Ptwjg4NwsBmMdEFDAImKuk@3Cw9KX5D@GgdMPMHbtreiZP0q/HY4WGuzfwSfpGBOZe4WIx3KmDj97WDtXh/s7Rx8pBVdHz@4P9D7Xt6rba/MR33LgoZxe86u3@LkmX8DZdbs336UOqckglU5xgVfY@qeov7w@qh4dq/0DV3r3frRE0An9Q2TuqVQ8dVdvb2j3e5tt3gqD29o/Ubu1d7YiyHe07XKspZkXl1P6Oelc92HpLr5XN2m7t6BPXuFM72kNluNWvqPeVg6Pa1vFu5UC9Pz54v39YVWiYtV073Nqt1N5Vt3NUP9Wpqh@qe0fq8G1ld3eiofsf96oHipUEYq3crBKWlU3awqImbud27aC6dYQGRU9bRDxCcNdRh@@rWzU8VH@pUnMqB58cDfSw@tdjykSJarvyrvKGGmdlvkMV6pet44MqvCWBEofHm4dHtaPjo6p6s7@/zbQ@rB58qG1VD0vK2t0/ZIIdH1YdhbiGXDXBIGpROj1vHh/WmG61vSOaM47fQ9/Bpk7@SIQhLCtUdJsJDDUItJaItH/wCVBBB@4AR318W6XvB6ApU6sCKkCjYusono0qJCIexZup9qpvdmtvqntbVSTvA8zH2mHVpg6rHSJDDQoZn4h1qNJjbjX6ifCSR2JWy3Cuw92pajuqsv2hBsx1buKAw5rmFibb1ltN8xx89MYOUfwezgzcTvxgpTX96dqDc8rpE5nZZzShx6St/e0qzcjatVUqSjimWWdtwpVSPI1mmjCRXhMua5re@dVF3e@2erAxDYvJwUcnuHAQtsdGzJNT657oVfp8hQuk0/X6h0qdNrqH9brtPKRkAo3vldDH4PflsnUbEQoBO28c/Lx8KXRfTxBq44m@6GRFPVxAIKdQ/4movrkdz1b5fNPTxWC8D8Dm6CiQa5NLXKWQaGRjRwRriarkkwl@9zU7cMGMAZ9r1HFOCs1IztQL6E/3W/Qik0PsA0lnOe7K57GJZTT8L56pRiphlwj8R3sk8FtcZS7wvN8vMoV4ddjz5y56vWbGtk0ZzjukfeBFxv5O8XPvYqJ4drI8I8vXzjqKQGD23byECe@fNcmU7pfcgFuWwZ/6kH9sg434fMCpKVfFh9X60DLzRIpDI8lR2rUFzCu4k7Hme1f5pfYRu7nC8rPSxPe34XcZW9AXhBNbmvBOuNwZ/7w9kww0wNgXB5HE1x4y8vlYGaNvEma@oYyXyHTjN6H5Q3P1pcfzOpGEFrJXbjteJ2bjgT@KY09y@M1B5d3m8c4OiU5g@2xt5flqyQrdbv3iyO8n1MOeZtnrWJ/mcVqncVJslGzRwodHSszDd8T@zMD5PDLCdbvpNP4IPw@h3kZSkwmCDM0NELmoCxW9lAc6pBQ74HhkGX6dOTI1A2QSTbXRmo474iW@S2sl5gGtzNIec6@N8Aeww@FvhnjYIM1AmsXY9y5xLu0uWO6ldoyqKG9u2HEPsuRSho/FjVtIAz7qYv1ZWNfym@btWC8GosqI8crdziUJiUeTWCijV9GVkf2e/YzoA2D2HkZfftH8Ro@ftIM7dnfnBsPK8JDIuBOWxDl1dBitG32iIZ8hjAacqpma1hVO@W2NFI89fZwcOgaJjQZGBTFaoOObBFwK/YhMVskasK8XbPVVOBXOOwCnpDlWvxPnzmqOhlIy/kP0u/FKoQRW6OREqHYT1mGZLJ9CPxaGnAky/RQ9GP4/kCYz4K/TjpOgR9SKOQF8ECUZqtCKtq9MFP/GXDTEbjciasY/fYrA3MY75jJsmL69GYl9DZFA987YfPjEbg9bmRkEAJPjYCM@fkOVtEuXtk6vU7YujnuSbqPTzyg9V5ipYgpudvXM4WWXY@5W8GIrW86aYhXuUlH1WjZu5zzqacs0sZVXj4OUgLON/4/8Ih@AhAOeufRStFYnOaugR5mRA9rVUmzCaYYek2hZenvnrd2iirnITMh@ffNlCEWgN4DPdDs5pkhPiXpu0uMiz8TqiL3gwZ84tsmYfLTLunNWxGx7gPO4yYchCDsyvMEE0Rbo7KovgqYyj1lRBJVEWoeRn0GIWztHpOVp9SbEnk8mwaEh9sddcWTvyamWyZETBx8aw7i5fE69c8eEcvthzRYWyy8e9hzoLqIyOZbQ5RFipdHrDWjp6KLdhKPjj@2c@qgPHbxucDXQ/gtpPvMH@kTCLPqpGiybZPfO04z4kGfUAn8Ia4VmjvmDm9TxoCEq7klG2VWVIeY1PLphDh390VJRZdajlHWiCbslZSKuq1X17ZvkEoJql6EeU9APws0F62xyPbh3CIffTW/wO@Z@LIG6Ta8ZeiaNgeSzQOmkWpd9PDaG0vR@L@ATDeoKnICElCjKQVqoqEpz9HPNTlqvKRV5x4TvUm7Jj9cTMqnRlqKKIsbVtRPzrWapM0GlZe0aNHQWWlxeYVRmbbhu79yMsbfQ5LW1Sp12Q5HyUhYR5cdm6YgnkZvh0yc86UP@8uMAo4e@4I5bL0GBMNasuFedlnOMH3QKPvreoBk/E6WVTNPt4/iNtz69LvOiOTrUbv8a7jDwxrQDaOT9UZ5h1DN/6V1261u9tnvh93yX9mlwAz8SiYfHMT@iwy4GvZuAowdxQjOWqTmOnsW/jLhhw3t4L1mKueYKhl4/E1dTGA7GlUtxE8En51ACjMKJMn/3J32khWWerUSFrKT9KevjFe3SnWWfFmcVlht9ANACbmNCg0JsSIdsmBQzPi1NZTi/L0MMx3OVVa59h8ZeAuMXRCK@hklgbJCZUkuINwI7szsxPmmOnCb7IBzA0ZK37SEUTpDhz46LCM0kRV5BU@ClKq4VYkXlFmUEP4R4GN9N7uXn/2DsCYGfQL/4dBa3zGIEFnEt420pkP2K9jJKuLB6oM8ymiUxSTH/wu/GzA85CMVoEmoyeXwXNVjzhxZF2s3eFFdiRGZo44Mgd5k6iZz62MaksqAWbPbbgSVIZZgp3M2w3vf0Z3nw4xJXTs4gmLY05EwM6btI1SAqIQbuhHptHGXxqfz9EbO8/NBemyBgeZbKWSwWcyZlVi5sgeLL/Iprrd6AhHFqgnpa1WMhGPb6Cw@k3p2yY6Zntlm0btj2dxWBhdnKNFkuNpm05TEexyVrEp8JpklSjDXNiIewfeXnkM0niTgq1zHeyvXxd@hwF80ivalwUgn7uyljH5PiNTR6zUQTDinGHU5KS@H3kzo1vH63BNEwZXtVZ4lRh8ioj@UxBmqCTCGVHk4h5j6N@wQ9mkQ51Nsk2sX7506iTirJGZenJinh5BL0hON2GG2SXOq3oHwBN3Gywg2FVLjgHDljvsorZs/hZBgJAhCrYi8bnUPJCW7UWRN8xNEBWpk6tIWKkET0tBHXcAid/ocEY6/8@nBHazzUx9niWUkgjUJItKvgXPdBMvbm9HpSHzGUKVLQEJ9BirBFU7Lp8uGt@tm2UD6CIKU5WWv6Fhw0xlZLhA39iSfVR1gDR1XpkokRlRwIdRYNNBZol3LR9mS7itWfPxCOh3aDHka0gZDPGfws6RJw571aCKmNIqPmGFlsTW4ZbbbKbkiRiKHkHeTXQ1GWurxxJQCeYEzly0WCALemjD0uBdj1TpzzEojqPqKC5SKGJX1kr6iRnueMdBBVZ3i2EstRmJXjRRxGdiYQWljMzhMhQmuW2VkiKDTRzcQlluP57PZEOWhBbHhfKE5doXslScOw54SAHPO5YEcS5aSonILmYE58tmInEkP@5tQXhVhqYTKV6BNieJItTqauFRKpiWqXl5NFEyWJHna81kQikcKOIxxKhZ/7x6YpcZfnoU5obJORWGVo/WzE5KZdJu3bcr8Fap2Nss0aw8CLW4ab7VddQqwknLLf74BdLfCVAXy3/3RrjWaqwUTHCmC/dMbYJSMbQl6xpjDVo1nY6RpPe6GDArOn7bXUh6OdnYTb1/OxUTTqeIOVQqEAJj6PO783utU4SvJ7@WTufOuq3c73b/4y@HCeZ9nveRwS4KXZQXvUJTQoglxvcCGRIYADZUXurDZkxV7/qtWKh2DADSU6j7pNcmpvCIonID9UevlwxAdADFJPsL@igWjfryocfTeuLDQ1FHMNRaWhEnydMrdnRB58aEE/O7ypYmAQzEabieYtu7zxFTMIIptwZ7H7YvtrpJ6ceuu12z1HfUT8YXgKmLudLLCzEy9QkCy4YWTr3quA/dE6yrv22zG7YmSJ8zrAmYnJxJkwfuHhG//Au6iO@pnUyecUTSvU5CU0cwn@qR2VukjZ2ln8A8AKHxLaD8rdcfuZBtNpMjNN9XoER0@E0dOiM3Pvk8hi85mYptn3c4Oos9HNsbMGarrNawHjy567l1tyR/aQuKnTUbEFGhYEhsYJPlceVgKmZv84sXg9bLUeJhU5DIB07A9JRImE8nMCke8AeATq4Uf0hBftf8rSsN6ZcCgiCxwE65iWOyhQRwHLetwo/3GTqVQqar6/tKQqlU16yGZVZbOitvFhc1Nt0/sm3p@Ul1dWSiJzt@2v9HHTfLxVmwSDTziXGpeDbXqltDLsxqCtjS6ez5fnndJ8vby@UQryJ5VNmPXT03//87/@97/8W76iX/4DL5v8cvI5zJTL5fLzja/zT25LeD/ZPluYPz@Z758tXJTAZf/LXsN7tWHWjdRHc4NzKy2zQOwr65GafTZ7n9FFlYkJ2HEHv5N0eanSjSCf1l8DiRzFMjbd8GLfPdhRntMW3gQdmNzKExJpAjrGcTz1TsODAh7NN0RJwgV6oFJe7lbMwT3cwYQZwluVtPbEw2vWaw82LZEnBdji0oyV9buB18UJ@DWveaV5luXSrz@sa/7Nf34XXGz2RmrxNKMWC2rRUYupFP8UV1/QV3s@78M6V7LRdiCVciglulqAmqEKfF7o8f6BY@1MkNuy5jlkDyAZNxWcWazgnHD3x8YyEnAtuLDmEIpTyREJXzKhSPrrfPeWuuUr5bhNJUxteKFQ17sYrix2oxL2L5ZAbiCKAFHNHSHIyx5ViZs@tkjGU9580X1tcTQhBgyyHrzZ4XGPDzQXzXe1znNiL4UwR6w@L18xN5bEGJrRRorUHyHAFyqynSywJeFCesESLe9YK7mZYoUdb59mPtF1GHtDo5suhf5UMSYQbe444ea72q5FK3LL9YpK@eH1Sqyq1KTut7JiRTpX7aHf1@YKXDsG1NewtlsZSehRBiRwxGf/y@kRxgcFxlPURLdIsKyxavbQdBkJXW2aTh1s5@TmKEaE/OcMje1vE2PbzrOViGEH4QFGKlTla7l@O9BeVwZM7At3cI7ogG6LA6oN5d6Mz/MQfXUC414rRDrHkFnlPBrP1JR0f@BedFxHpfd6RwN3XKNpi1Y@w0bOphbCBROQwODTVc9qnkFYWqS7hCkSNoU1hxC8oD3W4dGkb1OhzQm61AwF7XYFgyDBTkxJ71uiryboGHH1D3RCHOUp4R3eRmoRy5IXmkYaUipuNsPDbGroWKaG@NgJB07KElTDkWl4QRe6wkTb4YtfkuRt@AjQdae0FaA2RVh9gfoxO114XTcxOfXbljH0z5eUzIsYzxyKUrSRLBMntRhFvANWtI78nPQCIXOTcWdkzWUyc6eBDueWjs8j7OQ71MXPu8oPA9BxADO2DFHHXV@E5cQMFcXAyKkaa/4ThFbbvSD8xjfuGKx4ms68epS3Tz6fds8WM6fdb6dfbMZEi2Qzy2ZVWl9mG4mlxwrNjHkn8Wq00gLjavC0m8xw2lViwxIjASGSz5x8zp99yxNCp2nEpD9NC0ESXQZM8vfXlwf4/BSa6SQW@bQ1Zy/apvMzr4q2ormVf9GH8sGWX8LCbCr5mJ72OYMWgWI73T@uxOQkyK8tF54tF5/RTujCG2UH3hXm22xwde6NaCkRYDtLU8/plwQ3JAhxOwrcEn0cUTslrInYngTaSEmLUD3MuR4rZCsqkxOeoPxEZXaXChMXO8zj4vIRG35HEcuZvOwLSlQHY9yXwfwZ9Dqoxw0g1yatQ4QjoWUgOiJ8hJoFZBN85S4Otc1wWWA7p5zagu9WBkLdm0/HZotur5vVizU7t1DCIhpWM@21wlphcoxODdHECJ3Xi6mFR6q48er5f/37/h/pYXpjOf9xQL/D9B/p1bW0PNIDvT01b9fpjfQ6sq3epsd52gPT4/P/@k8qv/EXgoOU8Tr92VgxsFbH6Y1smYt8S2@s0kNxeZnq/Z@//Y3aMC87NsRina87ihErGYpsuV3mXUpXNbRStqULkVhhwyzAEA1D2pvTCxSjRstrBT6mS2utimtPe74y@ih6imfFrCGrCslJhtGnoJWRFCijgqyANCoULRXT3TBqG2DeCE316@PcakA7gF@1OkdYZai68TiAytC8bIuoAzNSI@3n5WGj8CoVqne8TBmdkpJZQmJrp2Xt2tPS/wE)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2dhls)

Tcl/Make/gnuplot/Pyxplot code:

```
set pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';set pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
```

`1/2` is `0` in gnuplot, `0.5` in Pyxplot.
`set pr` is `set print` in gnuplot, `set preamble` in Pyxplot.

Answer (score 1):

## 350. [rc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc), 15870 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1 1 1  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#-e                                                                                # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11 xxxxxxxxxx                           #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.-._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print (349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68)); exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #   wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c9tadiD4Y@oh80dcgXomKRIAAX6TImVZlp/12rbctvze60fRNEiCJJ5AgAZAibQsV3fPbm86ycxmejqpTieT192zme1spmqyUzubzk4yU5Xsj1Op@Sl/gPOxtZXaSv8HveecC4CgREp2J6ma2lpIBC7ux7nnnnvvuefcj4Ou7o1@9rMEXuyxY82HluMz3/B81nfNU8OV2Z05u62bXlHLCwLG2nWH07Fh@15NSDCVMUu3h1N9aLCBafmGm2WeYbCuYTlnEK4xtj21p57Rb8JbnjHbOGMHds/sAwTmOyeGbb4yXAgrMHbXsF6PX/us54zHut332MQ1bZ9Ci4w91uFlMO2dML3r@a7e803HhqASY89sSx93@zqj6BPX4InKDED1TijNckiFsYeO6xmQg9MzPM9Bzyp46q7pPNh99NGl@GqOfaQDUhPLmF3KXlXZp6bh9i@n0NgnR/fuXfbNs69Ijs3uXUVJLbDdqe8c@JfhF9nu0LB1pslVWbscWAJi@oZVyVVyS0EQds90oRb1oLZYT7ehVrDOtpgxnvhzJvF61i0rqkOP6R6belPdonj2dNw13DCi5@uub9pDdmb6I@aPTC9KR7G9id4zpL5hmWPTN/rMMiGRMwigAGi7z06M@ZnjQtUGMB3bmkNCo2cOTEwS4gEA8Ur5I4PDGetzqEzbh0bAdOYBGpYRQksLCYh/1@hOh8yZ@pOpzwC3vunpXQuAduesbwz0qeVnWRfCgJjkfzYy7KDRAjgZQBw5HKsvpoSasWjber/PctBeAY8Tg5lANUKrxvJ58GeOC1SDWCFGATBqv7yMxgzqBqp84NRYMZeD8P3IB7HVLc8JkFlGDQNt6JNUZwj3sesMXX0M1OgbRNNPDh4zr@e48AY/jMv7zXVgerrPtrdZcv/R3SRrRtUiu10hqqIGO4cqSISB7FS3ptBC4jXhQP24UWoBqyy5kayxJJBFy7FCgRWge1aYVgQiqbkqOKCfa3kVfiWmVVhBhZ5STGYxn4GrD03L4FCGCKWMDVwrMg3uuQLLqxUec@hYAx6tR5mVWb7CSmVWLrIy3KusqkFuCLrA1GoRfiX4AbQqoKLCL1/ggBbtHtoptrU9NtDHpjUPoBP4HiuqrAwQAV8VIGsVgADPfB5/efgRWstXHLY/AmqP9FMAL1nmCXIdI2I8WIUKPJStLYU4H7JWnr03wuyBdEC0YoWVIfsSUKIAKABltQpkX8zxgngjw7KCZCMPkxG25Rz8APMy0KEC1M8BLXNIzDL84B34mgYMTANupQED0lTw18CdxywgXgnCSlCVpYBeI907gYx4PlqfiA@cG8CoSG1kVioSCSBAbbE81FmJFaAh5LEhFPMM8AdcyiUG/KqiskqBVcoM6FnNMagbFfDCVqICn1QBHxWBQf2r0ABUwEkFaqsAVM0XmRAjtprHcEibh7RAGrUAaQrghopTS/iDdNAyVMhShTw1rbpohICbVoTyFvPUOrUS1G4ZwoBuGuCqQXPSAFutAuGYtgI0rGDjLSeznBA60gFqBZs7tEMgRhHwIbgQF9xaOc/pp1uTkd41fLPHU3YHmLSE3aCEZISkOSwePAtITUAlB2CwFwD6GrSAPJAjD1WbL2D2FwJ0YD4sx9kfcIlPsesjM0OGDczKIVa8aJMpO2Q3aeCOy5wTWJkFbROGi56ObA07uUFMKoRj@jKDTGAMNZxTHPOJ0yxl4xE36ro4xMPQ0Tdcl2FckAu8LPEtb9r1jJdTHJwWeA2AERrALwe6aUUIUOfUfeKq8Ex6kN98Ge2B64ypB4@RL1mOM1kzBgAXPENA950zY4H6gknqk4kFQxH4G3wkBGTOdBJWSLKJ58oRgkSYrjcyASBlBSzcdI0e0T4oOqTOA7NfRrHGtOatPEK5Exuj8mziAP/2MI09tawaDB5Gj@WbSt84VdCHj2PL4xfiEI5sMD4FILo6CBqIOWERQbqlyTRmHoU16znj5aJxpnUQFX1k4mhjnelzqL0B8Ctjpo9BHGIoc9gwQo6hxfAaxJoAgQ@LdcD6jp30IyhnLkgGUOioJCR9IE18c2yA6OhAEqzxAiGNLJMw686hKRO1CjLJihyTS4SShcuE4h6FmAfvLDCG9qc9pBrmbdrUgmDs8VBwcg29z/0E32XHxzr8XBgkJ4F4LKMDIz5F1GJSHIywBlA/EGd6BBEHfsP2QCbzZGai8Aotf@gMoLGdmVB2EJcg6QJ2j4iAJIi8ZnJPFojk2IDGJxYzWW8yYeAPQgg0z3u5CozrzhcmewWB1gjkst7UdedsNoGaMMcQy@85gwG03lfGZAQg2LjPevMedE@oZGw9Qt8hjtSbLBdz8bZpQBwbJb29x19jQwPIDlLAAEV7bPKLAkwmVAQihW5zCcHWgVJYhN5kTmQBMFGKgePI6N93DI8ai@OeRF0fM/OMIXUN6GeDBTMao8QDrdQmSa0PnCfoXggfMxRWFgazClrBR4YNXacHrRI6PVQf1ukuG4CGEpMLUHjTez1j4gftxCF2ZtoxIerwHgpR5CsFwGRvJGzeZtuXWg1EjVpOTEBAoRJRnwSynY68NlCDQGSwjYUczzmLNb@SPcQ4vZS7@ALjLGHwQlyDw4S6BEqUxCSmPrIS5I5mb4S80EduQ0IM9DZ3erX44BfP3h0zaRDljdiowHYEWYm8EI/1MCT4WVcByRMLYTWXPDDqkscNoHVvvAKyEyFp9eO@sqLLwBRvAjp2bGcFVCBmBBejLIdQXVBjfIpcQ7eixkjdxVuqI2TYC80cBzIYQycTx4WewZnOnNQzqrJY6wq0mlQ0VqRBq18eWmHISOKA7@MoCAkmFuhy1MWwp4K4qgOnACbGtQ7geQ7PMYYw9XqCFeB3RqyfNyYYS23bQIlXd@ccCBQPhmfIaM5M1wU2eIqDBB@DwsFEpnYKYwLoX8hZkRzU7y9nLmOL3pt2zdll1aaHnvIXnnCqu2yAWo0LQgd0olRy4CXTdfKnlLEgUXEmvkJJ@V2EiBRJhipPDUBRgkHiHjCap3O7lxKXupiYZeLUH1TENDgwIZfR2Mf6xL@M3Rfgh41mfAL9mt7qbAjDtyTBXUI/wgQDFBkDdBfkDOiEILpXq/2uzl4D9wAVfbZHqVHIpKcqF6K8DLsf5RUQAnGJl1fmWXhujxxSbFTDEmB0KjkNEksEfEdKUEIRPBQlGFvRg6Q9HkZyDfec2jSJwVJcFEmz80jYhwEgRciYIHyYPdPvBOLKrVuh4LLRaEBjA2kK2GY/HVcTwtkeGTg1RJZJGgkykX3nqY99I5WG8mLkC44NiE3QUhtNdu6PXOhx9H4hQCQgq2BjSw4JG9TzI/Nk2r9c0TZ6YiQRex0ITWbPF@sCDP68NzSuo2pyiaqgSiSRqth4MT2BvtJ4yRcrVAyiuYaH4m8jQCVWwynEIGirK0nEkwZ@iwa9N@9ZgUjAXdDZOTfqAvonwexAxIiygUwQdtorPZUDwe7A4bDHu0f3G0Ff5IFK17RrSx6W09Mt8t7E6GKY9sHBnSe7T77WWQHDMru1yx6KWaiUcKidzqShPVUKslbbjMNYAL7buR42JlyOIwpBMJOcWUxUmvdgcJmF5Dx88pXLJAFJCMlBOYAbf5dEGh4HhC6hq3ujS4MwG2YykGWUJIzLpAMWwowciDqG6yE@j6evXmHlXUZqEvgjZtZU5wBCT@XADtPJGHhJAAuDugM@IlJakEJNG2dpF654zBCfj1BqvowMidKxJvPR4b39Jw0CG0xWSBRF8XyQpXS3L0Obt6Z9Q1gVB9gfuHosIy8QR3macF1J4F5vicCLumVr4AMA1HVkh0nWOCyaNwLc9y6XjXylXtQC6J0gXJYr4/JQ730RjeGBQ1wPVd5VoygFLAaryGvliBWFLg9bvWLRKBeq8WGrt8izHwdKM60wDoRyowtBJ56EPvJCigzE6gD9pw@uIO6REAmqgBRi5llMprw8S0DtRTJZ0lP2QENzLEP@lDieyMS0oiTDyVa555HyGYu/PzP9VC7Nn2oa4kLuu7sH2t0wcjAPSDMZpDSgLo4jkzvAxZGeB23Edixn6LAtSMOlwzBDEJvWFnN36NhXakhHTyxqAtdXgP/ixI0@gbHGfEWKI6WKq6t8pUa3vTPg0mopj0QiChEoheLLX@inOpBrUe6nB5/vwyCiFnO5yJ2jC0gQS0PkQlcv5kseTIKM5ACflQWM1lqu9PYwQIotdmChA0YXJdxdBK/0JI4pKyvjr0TpY@cKxb9w5peaFvjwpgWOGMkOHj1@cPBo/@HuZ8e@ViwuvRdy1RIQDvLrgiwkjzjdsLdu8a6JxUJwCegbLnYv4AJTUFDCKfip5wLjljGKzBFY02r4KlXqY2dkJ7305cKcYaj0hd3jTeghdj4eNUgIinbfQmXE5Ut9OJ5j@xn5/sSrKQr08tG0K4PSqnzRcyx9qFA6GBgsS1FRdTk4xHkNb1UKQMabGzwFn9wC0WFOM4i6NXZAeaEFQ2QNLMXB06yVZQ5HoAvjqqLhpuWoBVNplD5oCKArK1HZiAHTG9A2eIb1JPKm/YGqVXi7VnNaQRHDaEvdH@JuDAxQnVIwWgEp0pde2fGt41tsDlwaIV0GkmDyFk1yeAzHAouBIEmzpqjnh8QhboHzpcgriEYvpzibC1xKKeYKZbVUVEAtAzUNZFYJ59ykse73RpLvSABPcgY0bxBrhQOvp9sDeStwhMiC3PchFDXfen58bLdBQD@@RbjhYl5r3m6p7XSdXU2yFcRP16H1LhUP227oAW2XnNA06cnW8LO@fpWd9XXqXX2m@ONJMOZIE/ZwFwSpVw7w674R73uYQIkHKltLcRWM/EZZMSFkYVIBb0gpBToUjLTQ9BTESwKhF8VDaDnAt2IJ2GI2g5eDL47H@Agq3djuTSfp0cw/yjU4W@pNgIg02dxDLu3h/KAPo2PU8pFLQ@Uik2ZnRhLn0XWPz1ZComDhNEwPuloEgWbloxlpO1oShkZAqUg9B84B7QqnTUeLWUZU@qGlQYaEE04@gARh0@rBEPgMJOYF2eUF4TmRz3KRTmznzEZoXYNVpK7p88l@Z@riAqLZj5cNouc1HgegUeFifJ1WGrtGj8@y8sRUClACdTY2xg5OJYB0RazAoCLofJUSdUEPZ6yhW@UkXIYB@BK7vQdcrGfw@SJpjEoUNKl9lvRdZVf6XNGlV9Car5GtsPC78WV2qvSjkADLa8Y0SxLMgJJ04owp0qc034KBd0JxV5jM/RGUGFqYqDeciWFf1vm4RphK12ltN5kEhm/aqfPkxsZGspZsJrPg2gHXNrp20JUB1w65JHJhPBldlCJLLgxtUQr0aycvWiHkWbqNbWCGksMrc5LSW7Vavp3VW2rw1PCZhqoAykNsCR8AJ5luNNCZTovNM1yzAfk9VvY9bDtPe645CUjwMQgE/D2gQZ6IAOo9SvOuUUfd9HqKjBsuKI0GipgpN3ncyh23j8@P@5nji2QWU6fregP0Q2BefmosD11nOgHBrVWoScDb0q18rV3vNpK55FYqVZEsyEhPpz@spDM6p3UqaUCbSh0fJ4GkAXVavZFL8GZZLZ2OCAV4DEzQMiwrlZTPK5B/N91OZ5KQNp3MAltuJJNAlx4SwaNC44wAb0T3zBmQEjomDHHxNQVikLQ4hd31c2MymrvxCNGsG0jZOIO@2ACA@ySQi8e55CuePi7QLWn6odzL44Fwi5N3KC9N5py7CxzTY2Vp@0o47p5Kg7Hj68onMihNcmy4TG4kFUmCkZBCOCQq9kPTwy6s24Yz9eIzjSsnQDF38D0aTYFZhnt7stCqzIlg9EYOS27eBugsWu/BoQSXriS@ABYC6Pdk@CETRakEF0tAuqBdGibwRdrfQrMyKiHBWU84N18sTV7KUW51SsNymJE5tB3XkIAkkEKgLSm0oUlosmBXzAHNfF1ZlwhCaUhDxds0gCPesxydaMvZdWw9aDKOpQf9HJI8MfqCBfxjAOxR5nXhGn1lS6BVWscdwQgBpUFOrEW1NQ4CFMeb9GV/BkmFFA648UCu3YHQecb6mqaVesVBLQzDVgHEHkEloVZqg4obBkkqBKaDSt7n00Khjv7o8O4@nzuhwRaHV5xH64yd/hTkykBvemLYwyzbh/Zk2s7YBDKE6V@dWE8cx@daPrysm5nhSrM5nlo6zflcnpa5Nl3P6ToWTQVdl3QRf@p6uqXzSagwdPeThyDrPzt62pBrsUiKfjq@Nm@ch1ydLafnQXzNkdZbw@UhjzdMcbMo4rgVbplDNhMElDBgGmyYgzoK/cvoH3YpXEMJ/CvoP8bNciArB7MI9Bp5BhGrFBE30OEuosDzXM1doP9aHSyKp1I8LjgusD1XNfI/9QeDJe88eZ9IyJqshXeBvPlGuiUdMY5SkUfCXXVLceKAShQn2lx3OV7AvKK9BiPDClcQn4BggqtkMLZbKD6BboKSON//ZoAgPcHFEOLQuMTGeiBrelemLaBPTSQeW0hsUD@BMUxByUXYVFgwxV2nnmI7wdKkx7mnA6o9zZ5sN/liNqpOLtfaFD75vtkBENvNerhZaV00zCmZjKIRVMINUlAxaf3@SlGj3RgezakLlKQueApoDTMtJx3Pyvvt10nFIzIMmHh8PPswp30G6gfuNNu8pQyNOma4jl71MCQZiKrdOZNAsMNYfH66NwJ2wjKzZVJC/UztgWP1Jb4YBu2CcTUKKyjYixDtgAs2OhqmG25@o92HPCmy0di@uStwL1Vp82qE2E67CBD0knP2@iR7@pq1YGQ7lb2JZfptdiH7TmeEJPGnrn15Tx4XNV1Xn3tCsJWlwXaffPRJK9fmEISxjgtcFV6Ls3BrJ8jHIA/hXltw4YYc3/RpwKcNByaWV5UBqRmthQD6AINnUGdRRkGJEPXXxutFWQYGKKQpAzH35uMsM9IX8sDSfd@weZvjq4zryc2Xg4JsGpT9TrC2UGM5WoABAdTEMECxzp4e3d1/8kSGluulkvu4UFOD7qj3RiCHrCt0SMl44Wvsw36SfYhp0qidC9DVQMnoBOmhUdeh0YOaAbkjixgabgo807jG0gNvWtaihFwQCwiE26p6PtEoApYy0lAmAlZbif8zm2tUAZ41aPEZoiSQO3WrBrQ10/LUNl/KHownJJ5ClCTXSWFYaGymiKltqmlqPa45xhViUKRINoQStFpMegVMDyKLrN2u86V@iIt6ljtE6ooiVQXtAG6oYdU3wBskF4IQJG@8Yc9bOanazmyuAkV7yILNu7z8MbgIYRm0Z6zMdjNF/f1KR@Y48CU/zsifkdZ8aYd6jW1yh8inlil6uC@KmA5to1reDrW82Qo6GbISmnHBgoQsIRFsrQ7aLIUT5wfVBpORRyrNziOia0hy9vo10ZBtaoxoCC6V8cq4CJVMYEwPHCjNg2BbdVwIoN4a7BfBPnssiKE2tbwgiyFcUldOLwmh0qkYT8eFQNM@cWhZJ3J1crJaRMEvSj0@sa6mHJjeiG5LUSMceFxtHXbeuDug24oItLoRrJuTB82bByIvyIq68oQeNIW@IuflvSJL2XaNwdQe0iIjupn08oaYUrVCkQfdrrkuKhABt3@FzxXRgElhe9bkgqyG@7RxxgXGI2BcXElZFP3yNiO2RHcYHXxIFTz/y9f7QP@rtTOCgQInGCNHB4ZurClpsLaygqT4QrfVFcvnwaeWqRNhyHUTyJ7uQpF0K3KsBk1r7ZIEw/8YVw6CGoe2iTcQDq9pZhxzvvAXPldnsmrtzAaW2VsX99K2K54VrfKA/tYnInAhyDQoEbEuXgnGjK@0xDRpZGM3IxXujWLUmHm9j6b@lN9BPr2xEs0J/q7rm0HMXFHvqgZoiHrXNK6pclc/mfYdaXIyjOTU0oq4i9LTUq8E4kCw6ttB5@ri8wK65hDG2fC5LtpiaFPO6HFTq/DsqTeRuqRs9/kbdYTxNTm4Fr@vi2IGB5wix3qqmRbd3rElBtChoQSbHhTcUirFiGZeIrOld@cog4zev5VFGwiA4zR6mUwuv2YFeTJZnx4VRkpfra5OPZN7nB6rpgIUvm1V4pNlVOBgI@sNtQrDlTnWLUnrx5xrmfmq/QdXokZLl5TGOMWFm9OVNbegPg5IvamluwvXNU18gUe4WrBu4jkYNh6bPQfEgQlTy7KqhUNHbMAglhnugFtkhLuG6Rbb5WCuImMf1EIcxKXItZoFOD0fd4auaVPvwND4jkzc9xprJLKzjlI95wx/a8WHEaim/L56RHu1Eqt3YE6S1bN0GMfXDgdLc4A4x3hDQz0zPYNuqwl7shJRv2et9F/uAuHsXny27qZm7ZmW47GndL@OQEMXqMDvqxt0nJambks05x13X8ODwq0MiwrVraFjlSpDRYfb2lqfugPk@8HzXTlcxKFU9QYOFYo/jq0Gz7V8/URxT26qIDrs5eI21pjzmiF2FZsKlljWlw4UA1yfW12ye7kKpZQVPqO3JmNcWTnT5@Hz5xg61pE2HDomcxKnQbrDBNUKOHyXi9g/T26F63PrvxtTugK2fFMhYpV7YhkwWNH9SpUyLae@Zwo1l3t3FjWwpsbUWKloHHa/MPDo8TVKxrsjlQuKsRlMyOMaAJ5AiWK9CjTDd8Iax2l8u5aZ6JbZM24WZZaZ2gSk7wmqzo/B8RgdV1MM7elkqVaXtDP7yfUkG03CLu30l7DDkPflQ5UbJKUl@dwz6HetxsQ1PNwH1ijkcrlAgIktrCy9XKdJ5aO0X5j8vpQx@SxyXsTFxTQ35lydB5ElvtNwLQvS1in2FLlaVWzTNvw53t@Rm3Ydx3qfmgKm2jdRFAPJknbUXldjV8Sd4KwIW0xdeDjh0R2sm7Tgo02gWwJ9UGm@rtLjKz/vVJsSrm2Ocd1p@fX66ZvYOtJNueCZbZwT4ntsrfWyZDAbosoVuXxtr@MSqtM1LJ0/ZqXCdfCqcv5aeMtMI1iTxTVcvnK7WHFPXGJKkzkQy@yDljIyxga9XiPl6300LxA81kaaOfhbFzwzjJ4y2zd66yJMTOALNt6XlopjwpLv2KBf@bidD/UUCzeMBr7rOHC4uLeSyAdjfWhwuxbXccrFhAVumuFq3cK5euqixjfK9CDZwpDB@iYBnerEmHvhcyXAh/Me1Ot0fPN026XO38M50Hfo7et2ql4dYu2RM7JHxohvD4/e1nUOaI8@t0NyHeqA9XCEO9Ymk6Wd7HF6Wo5lvQs9kTVyRuk4g5U47eMZVzyg9V5w53oXAoLHjZN3us95BzrW9pqRMYVxyXN8Z2JI9LYuqoUTPfy@joeGa9E/7wzStXo@UCR8/rzwb9Qth7rjTyb06EysqUc3SirR0eSb5KYB34FCex8ddyi/csZdOfCUg@0ptAS@msV0Tb83wrPhvGUbQ6fbG5k3Id01dN82T5Rwyoe/vpPuipQxmXQXvWXLBPK6cxnbSyMe/hQfB@sqPZg94sNa5LhGXlk1Q0enr6WJftLz@GwoulgNJ4RjvZGf0a7RKffay6npL4DGtixF07t8WQId63APNkmslazoKMSCDQebJ9a2UhLSUSCXjBwIPOq6bJe3s8W6WD7Pb@sQipeSMIptP3kfcgdbfGh20IzN24L/Uvta2pu0cpCzR9Ohd5Vh8un6PohoeFs/bUFblmNT1jBm6XbwWEdmzVLwLCM8OyBzTY1r11SK1y6qUDzVknTHhEcHHlB107VzaJY58fidSYO1S3HBliXQxS@vF3LazFcr00HF9I0BXwJB100i4thxccMxyCBSD1fScQYdmTkXvDjjsp0hMHXJYovIYdx1YsvK3UCrqz8aM6XPHhlDHbdUPzB93JO5olVQk121i@hG2F@d6p751SmUbF1jQ8MMfBnSjZ/gx7cV8B7qQ7N3f6kiIiQDAgcbOvljqfmj19W6OBuZHu5oihzXTExhk@ONGFtdB/SGFTEvz9tHNikWHYifdlwZe9XcujOZ46GwObmum1Y3fZplDZ7rVMd1e72uReJsOp5MveCxGgfaMxWfhR6fkL93ZgJw6SWwVjbSLX/1THVsyhWksGBQXDjXSeOfm5YzZJ9XcgyENhDCUDhf0XDuwPD8GDfkuPaKlkh5v@OyJ050SC4v2EuoWyPPJNM2/etnc3wfN@eETywMHznwIILyAO/y7feFIB2tpsiDm2X9xQnkG8Z3aHlPnanbM9AZmRWJqwVBrsZeuMkYD244aBblLK6l9RwLuhc4rJVdpufYU19yp/a1o0Lp2lGhxmaVUqwZsNRX9x8@S8dbA23KvkkKNUD5m3rWfOFau2HgUiMzbRDE1vPR5dihLnGXm0N6QjuCb0izizabesSu7zqr9J3HcxhA3llhAuY/Hd81erhseGPej5yHju3AaDQBRjl@YvCj/UsbPVYnxGQP8PA60Kd/YzZPCeyaQYhLG/rE6EL9WgvXu4xFHPBd3dfXDEU0N0j6X@S6sa2YVtdwv6BJv5h7nUq7jNB9Y0a6xfoGw/ug5Pd6XCTG@bilPrK0YuNNHMfmd@K2OXioD6/nKjAU0O3dF8pl3G@/NC@wUj9bLurhKd8lYvS57Yl1ZXWNrmPx@zV7kmyT7wnQXdPwlAdoyoD8SgUmgfTlXctDytfykIVqBJLsqe7RIv1qVWMBUp29xxagke72HFwJCxzX7M6J2R@4gU1HW/j5xoEuEH4GHEvvTQNDizehZY27Y7qtVRhitfnE6OLhny4Z7fD12dXK5DNDgcWC2I6u6Jx/yK6wU5dY6jFoI@mbh60lPWqZquaEbsSp1y6X02YdyTaN3isdZ80cotdibnopHMqsPCLnmrnqWDeiWWRFpwPtK3vS8tY1EGgsQ/JHLuj8in/d9HZoTWXFesh0bOAi8/IqzFrR1fFGVFhn9Xp6xFxdQwpM@gEvicz7cflQ2l0reSJ4@D@887ECg3CnVAgtjADrunkFH5CfunbweJcW@Njx/IE5OwS88RTAOnaCxSpCEnjwnoGurXWFgNqzpxaffRjG9l2N@6SOSWTBVpIsYte@IRn2qUT23mZXS@Tws13KLlo@9Y2@FJg7wJUG6UF4zCuKFjxXLKDGeSNu9lQVTthZqRBs/1xF3LOQM4C85fjSxKOnMvEeHzw4PJInnrpyfNod4emIK3Lckv0ErZKLTUl9obux9U6@Ha1ver5y56kq7T04kDHCGnrzFQ0JHrgyt/RYO@8ZmBXVFX2tFoShhr9aQLx/9PBBZnESk6X2Rq4zNtLx4L2nT7N40uTjpyuD46nvQe8YOLO1yQ/2VTW9ovk@s2l1cB33XJHTOkhHBmij0Bjvc/MrNwpXPWdi9I/mE@MTGDyRg3vvmH1pbSEf6afmEHshq64lFHVUVpVLhXRsZzYo24YbPdfV54k5QW7Zo4fCH2u3o6DkkFfc/Grp4boV/8tSDMsFOxHeL5Gau9pafVOCnjEcoUvRvb8vYqqqrqPzU30A9cqKaytrOcKq9WHLOX2HpWQjUF6kyEvyoVVJ5o37yMvSGFi3gjecng88wdlduw3mOgCRd2llhz8z7LluS7SWdZ14UYPUuKnt2iifG@@wIBXt8DlFQ88r1/iiLfUs1SNn@oaMj9xYkr29Owc3JXgS0PL6WB89esYe6x7aGrk@Yhxj4x0wXkhGX0g4b4WG7tYup/ZdAKVdC284Wd2fa@yp7vYdez67eRGOjpri0E42hCNY@EaRDMucmavGqh6f13q8epvRTXnzQxzOfEkOjtugCQC9/da/UNVcjiwM4VPN8dcbaibs4CyFLn2OZuviQUcHEWvoodwig0d6pTb6wJjhdhQ@G7xKqV85vpWuGfvK6fXDyXVhlWvCCtfkdyUMPVlezqnXACxeE8aKchT8wLHORo68p7uGt2L/8UqEritI9ZqCVGPc@VUlh5OgtLAYuNeL@Hh0IXisbK1Hhu8WJiOnaxZWlmF3gLYk2UO0iX41PNhOobu0vWXoBEc@@Pvq/M6mxsqMHuqvVgcQpzlZGQRM0BhN6UjE1eDlBdIuyLyGPTS5GUV2x/H36W0lko8d3LG@Msu75uTudLIeUWCJaMX/MhdfivgpqMrOmcfu4Im4hXS@QuXHbXGr/deJsiyaD0QjovePdsNGdfhU0WI5LrD47PGSN54Z9Q@fxvxcYzZbp@tKs3Wq48qQRa6PjgpL2W43n5@uINb6Y0YgZQAbjp5rxR/O4z5@epUToNY28sdWGPKxbi8mSpcqrO/4dMBwZeDj@Yx2T66s6RHfvLYqzF3RwPhxxydTO24R28sGNk348WB@KNOTQ7PlqZSdyaTTyx/eiJ8wRbuxqU20m7hJp0kh7uvXbCM4wQkBYngmNDiziubVQKM08NCpQCD8xiZk02ioxSrbwS9d1EBeTFOO6EVGrMK8WmzzPDiOWaupF2yjwcSayIIDsZFNWm5XFeCiRUgoE5NOVLbpQ8hmeJiT0ScC2GtGOigIvWoxB2@yEj/WXg@OuwJKm@ePDx7vPz3aPXr2tJVrXwTHYcNC2DbkFh66/zDfF6HsAdlgbONWlukYtgXZ0ecLUHf1wnIxKNmlojWWirYolLiDaTbPbVtR6ESwIl0AfpLIc6NQEFTRi8MOS0z1ExwGr/HDuXTGGKqIgxYpT6izGsutyniiA5/etIPwy59loVD8bE8NP9yDGQeGcaEhDh2nH@ToGezmK8zx3u7Bg2dP9lmI4KLRnJl9f9SoFrndZG6lAOppYNIWqQZLBkmSUFeNRvJeEgiTlJOsRme4yWYxtHOIFlIHT38HqbdYapPgAwWTUaUo/@XrykVSxt2@aYibDJFKQrbQ5KmhbGxssCNoJOzuk4NP9p8wxH//LnkjiRAEO8IDpH/24z63@h/acQk/WeSOibuSvQwhfog8PFm9OPyNNKeuO1n/4SKysk9HrCPz/tH3SQSBvv4A7faMTLBdMs@VJos5/ENLgfW0MCNqQqGlcJxYRktorsdOTc/EA96IwwANky03dtyLQsb4ZLaLX2XCbz/p9AkKQH1q@9z4T2AqJAEtTY5YTpZtErL8gxViLGJyewMae9eA8ZZ5Nmjrhl9jX0BLxMnbGjcAIEnN5JUkIegauSRk1rGIVyyZecqxq7z9tX@mDOsM3D64vx24Z7k78PYrwdsA3L/K3c8VbGhXLZ8tcIkjhNYKgxJwRCL6I@1jH6OyudGFBeHQQFvIV5k5hmo6JapjdJ4Dv0vAjhdwUq1PoNKguUGNBcYWeH6G206hucSaomCTQhlQpq3uxozvO7tkNrFULBVUBZCUTkOAZOd8iAdqOcB0ugbdRDg1J40XIGBsb28zERVBo1Gq85pVNu3nefFFhOgmxBXORohci0EaSLJIAWHNIBkMPhk1jUmReyXVJDKuvgOjEoXj6IXvdkAIkaWAWJxGBhrOnuF3y3x3Hpr/7OKXvmLfwNgMAEkqjEnkSotCYKbgkeND84FOuvjKDTdTgPsu@QiIdvU8/tU@srqJ7VG@2rMWp2vDj20EfU1GHsBB5XOXB9N43YqfIoinCKImrmq@refs2D@22wpvmwya6Q9WNGYb3L@sDNe0WV7u3as2F1OXLSYisdjtp7aDGu89KAxLaYqWV9RSelGkQmFlkYISBdlAcdDiy2vIDtgUsIyeYX7hTLzdvf2Djw8fP71iV5BiJi9HA77f3M4cS3K21Y4cyXixlqvkzj3l6cM798KKWCBdinFjYPxBSdTrSrKYyEKQi4MRl4u2CsPLpVuP8af86PRlfPPadahRoit4qLn3yJc2J0v36IjR5cy1yipqFYvXobSAp8RA7/HzoVdQTaXPL1rt7eaxnUhebQkrOsLzhLyFnQBcx97WpoKN/WrhsGDR9zSP8GNbXrwv5lf3RXEzj@at8Hi675wsDHsFHrGAWHnDbIBFCrISRl3b@w65jL4wP6fx731yQ1hxMz8xhEu56ygeA3UUfjoUucjCeGZgN3IEKpNldoXQvBK3HxmauYtMR3LTSKm0EHyCgWecCj4mOqvNZNqJlEojtyNYWXadKcoQXlqADo3S3eMpqGqPnQk3yU0rzneN0PXEAfYLijSpqgb7eDqGeAN6PDFo9h84twSJgZLJCFUuSwGXCCxRzjJo6xPya6E9yqDg8rhfTM3S8siY9c0h8PZUOgsc7UNVbbPIWiUWmqxT2kmR6mxRC9d2xY/w1G@c7O9lsnS2QEBv6TKowsYslTxLpmttyB/9k2efnibT4qq2RKZTA1ui/cs2VCP0y@r1nET3g94ZGihdxS2q1atcAvwuA@ZGvsLvAVWr8sgT6PtuDZTcn/ruA3CCGJEajPUJS01tbiBNZvSaOk7ZWbIcJTW5jUWbZTKkUMGDAmRGKQfk4uN3SrfnLKU0oBGgr2f38fHKnLCWKsttcFMmabaJ3@naA4kLLQOmBdCBIUmNwDawCYGaARjxTiLzBg5pMBziwoPMzK0Ips8W0SSpgzShUrPmLRb77tqy5ChWq7WgQpe5YpVB67vKDmUFwF7hc6FcD9QNbKcAzUD9lYXEgpFf5XgJyjfBEbkfGF0BdBIxu6ihLRYGsBZWS3sjF3@pfRv6CsgHtdqzo3udSloRWWS8ZeiafZzE56a9IxUv@BgLdFNlKWqyzjW6jzAZmsnrcOswaK3tHnUY8RJLTcTJcPkTyYu2qarXtvogYVALELOAA0BwyK0TgkN7kOF2ihVhq5n9z36GH2EWU5uqetJxTzPJYq4ON7VeZEX24eaxJG22co3bmzpoUf7L2THo5MpW4e6pMRp0D4bKsSiyPCsoytb5efLe1mPzuVZ6ObvIq5WXJxO11JJfztpipZE9abPHjz9703mTFmen85ficUqjjwTvHb4W1QIq@olalZ3vlPKJkyp@a5PpevGEzUBvZSfsFVwnA4b/5H7Vj7l1dHcHr@gbRUmRJY6P8ePKYllUlFayDf@k7r@Aiyv@rabclHfab96kW7ruz@bMNM2J1@/DzxmBBKmlnzLI9xZweoqvsGN6kgJF13g2WMwj6EW4NTU88Sjf7qAPWVyc7RrD4XRfn5vTe/7Dzz8Nr2d4vXqyYkKincmkJKl12bvW0YsJpuW0P/vJxkX2/HFn@8@@MVaMDXwc4uPbFw/R/VQtfrix8eGdO4VCVtM07n78@eOv7e7uFu5mi49bxZ2ClNvY/tM/2djQtG1N2Wh7ntpOtk5OPhO1XEGU/@xHyc7jx1/1vGb@//z6m6aKtzLcTlkZ@ARceaaCE@8V@KkoY73rlXiVgFauJub010mE/ucbTG3ulP/rdw9fJvxEU1M@deHpJ14mSpUEd4ID3vLh22mimdjGaKWLxFxpNBrgLP/Xfwfpmx8DHAyZb8OtWQxhleaJptSgJK8TzRI4VE2DfP/vr389hiFnEw0S48LrNmvBJRbKmrjThmuLrm0BjeJJOUUJ49n@yDccplZuqbfwxYQXeNgGGhE3/OMEfrmWHd5m7Ekrk8m05Y4El/wc54gUVdWOVfUWcAPpw61GQ9pi3OpfPl@8hQaK0zSjNXRgwDRusU//Ma7EKs/6zw3uiZAobdx@cbfZhELlm/mtZoauoCdRpypXRMe5LbIse5EEFaTVfvGA9xzWFHMVTcxms7w7zZBU0mzRkuh79wl@RT7YZdllv6UkECXwTbx/vMQ@Xn/@v/359/78u/T3Pfr9R7QaaPfNgbIFkU6hSzThul2r9ZpNsemK58f43oR2lKtVahWlc3Gc2gIO1H7C1NxHr5PFfPIpo66kMnacptRwUbbNIHt8byYW3k3u04z7BQE8MnmwoBTkWKIauSOqXYkHQ2uwv1JqnTbbEgpEDamlloptiacKsWxWWes2VJOolatiu6kVtUOoOlXkFTfa9JiTAM2wFNIxwLe5KFszClm8NeNeiWaYrLmI877xQnSbQqLVUtoGDQihH7u9Uduo1Eo1TelEnlcvVr/qZRjGYy9xmoguTp3EgqCJqGle9gurInphYQtm7xNPSEgG@we@EmwHrg34o3@4ole8b5BP4E1Rrl4brKZuaXml@GFpX3vP7AUYJ1iv2@2@6nVRDNC7ek9XfX2qz/S57nen3VkXZCg2hR/EnEXXdUUSEm9aG@wJ50Jtlgmv48yN1zNZ7gROcjj4kyRnlhAS/whXU9VUtgXjUw5uIJSRE3Rm/FNVgSXO4Wq/2Wq92YIO2sxsE3dsN6UAS3jIndvtjHRx0QJ3vR78bzcjZ50u7oLCtS8yme3nTRA9njdbGQD5PAApc5hyp9nepoAoryCzIHi7DbKLlNlubTecPfpBErikZMFJlpzbbYC7vYTr7dsZGVy3AUBzE7pjOpPZlKQNHBpbwVABkdvNTFgoxCEFwsL5@c/5Az0PeuzF9kXzorV9cbG9Df/bdL8InuB7sX3lnx6La02cRXgbOctxS2keK8cBn2jDu6w00UdWjsHRhCfEa@W1SruFDrjk9n@b/3J2cY98EOW2DFgLiS22lUATdvnElpB48fbL/wV/x2@//H0UFxn8GTUhcY69WtlCZbPKdU64MfuhzR7yywY3/sJX9EGPh030tPnNxvUoRXkhsxqf8k@plVJaxvG34ww6eCpeZi8gKsptMCwxUauUxE5GnWsssS2WyjQw/eKVK5lM/pMXWrWc5LMzeJj7hed5D2O4LbCDyHUtp0rq6ya3V86/IPGLq65/8ovrLiHxusqMGlCl5zFODyEBzSchSTBINbfHuNkXl0ck1ERPG59Jz3YlnDrRfVr86vFpgcbBfqNabfKVnc3H1FW27m7BXYX//Q0ohZDovsS/B6/wjx318O/JS/xjR6/w74mPf@xhF/@OXuLfbhf/jsb4d@cl/j308e/ZEP@OfyGfV@vi5jkRIKNW1YvNmUiEqCd2mse/4LvzmmXYLbPf5tNHLJUvVFk6cfwLxgw/xl3j1TdI/vQ73/hGstFISkn6uEVBdVymputAZEDdS9ZvJ4VEg22qm2rOyvVyalftgsNkOZflRrmR2ge5qaOynMFy89yc5caO2geXAX85cJm5AcsNWc7O2RARQsHld3I@ugbwGMLfAAC58GfiJrWumusxyMhCVYW@i4fgwfW6cyy0WJKJLwzQI2VVzskls41fE2mJL14cK1ttrVphMrYdudN6cZxso91prVpg3bmxcfyiwxIeaKL1hHJ8rARE0QpEs4uLTmf/0d1OR8Hx5Pihc7j4Pzwcx1@v/R8fOg8PnbED/4eHh9AJjGbmdgZY7e3bDWC9wWMn0azvHNeIgYdMPKFs7xw38xK6Sxngyxr6Zd7zWkCEZ3PjWEiepVCJOEM9ov7pWf20Tu6z8BUcnfoiQhiNO4InXGcwVoV6xRlcp2fooDd0nn16HLm4Q/n0DLw@ZaBBRf@gqcVf/wH@zf@2/h8@Y2mWarXTqfOL7RRdafxLp88vzi@CezOdSgUvqW34Qw94xyTnF010UqRzcLVS6Xb64oL7wT2V3uYAm5DNdpPSLuIBg09EWVK2/Jb6h31C1sF1nKwzYDmkJRdz1I8SYp3piw0yx8ezXC5d74Ym9HG5V39NuxDSdfpM2ma3pbb/9Ef0mYSdNEUqFup1dYvxF62g1euF8K1cqdcr4ctmKlW9ejVzO2oJFIlCIZ2u1@FlJwSbg9cIbAXAhi9FgGp4ei/gnucHh/QBAeAcxQR@uSNgnzn6/Ah@ySop1sRbt1LBF7J3dtO3bmnV3OvXkc9kAl7qklen0zfdTgf9869fix2R9qtUi/Ceq7x@reaqGTWZdtzUI/wEGmSVklT2odakXKvAkrVCOf0Po1sAsOL2dqnQbJYK4C5VcOWcys7EzWTiPBzXy2nOG5ObClQr6j/Qu3FM8Nj5RYLqmBWK6RRw1zQIeBcJ/OPearXK/dOsUEpVMtXgr7EB6jWIK/wPZa58prBV3roN0iv@zVZeyJPr50ZDvWicGzWcHr@o94KvzeIpfePWrXwVaFjJ1Y@FTufu7tFup9MQRRFFHrihJ3F3AY0XuMkWVW@x2m5h@dq1@m1qB2qlyKDCeRwpCSMEq0CtKNpWUa0gKQRzgEY4oPyCSpTcYBuCRk@8CVVO3w3wBL0EM8dfHy7WZ102xIsNcaqTmcyii1mMh9O914siOfwKQqNXSotX5GNEl5B4/GB3b/8oq21LLKHd293Lak@f3Umo@FpcvFNwHt@f7O/ePXwGCR4/2N99uv/RwSf7zx6Dv8fOFlfI6YP74hl3rXg/Y58KX7ivdMPQjalhdM6m07OX7AvT7JhQg9YUCuEMXeYZHcB9oi/KUYdfz/T0L77Q3Qld7O0PvvX2B//d2x9@5@0Pv/X2h9/76Zff@xb8fgy/7/Dnd/5ttYj3n375L3737e/8EDz/I/z@CH4/@emXv/l1/qP3P4bff475/XHwi8XjPwFg/cpPv/zuj3765a9@H37/Kvh9/@rv136y@ve9b67/Ybrv/u71cb7z7@D3exxWGPc7v8P98Hkl/u/weL/6/be/8e/5/58Gf@j84dvf@GO8BS///Pt/@p/ffuM/aFrlT//N229@9@03v/H2m99@@81/qr39zX@j5uK33337vT/4qz/8vb/6w/@R/n9M9997l/@33//nf/G//sX//hd/GPx@Ar9/D66f/MV/gL7xt3/wA/z/7h/87R/9AP//53/9t3/w63/7K/8TOX6LO/6ff/Vv@f2vf@0//c1vf/uvfvL1v/n1n/zNb/3BX/0fv/p//eZ/@uv//vf/@p99Az1/6yd/9Ue/8pff@NZffvNf/uU3vlxz/9a19y/fwf/LfwSfd8fzXeC8S7ne1@fLnwufvw81FrlAO4HW/ctvf/OXoIH/BmNvv/VjPNQCvzX/P9ZUivNj/vb/AYd2tcwYkgMX/H797be@gyT6H4BE8B/R69vRy1IIf/n24gXI@tsrEv3yT7/8lz@it4RRa9KaCw7YFa2S2QKlZqtaDQbtYDkGkvzSMrQIQJDTt5FDLYV9G3nb2x98/e2P/unbH/zW2x/8Cg6YUqGa3c1K6g0zpBCx@A7xMGLpXeJhxM8w/wzNkEmZz@CNfRYEfvbZZ0LntYKnp26/Bt/PyItfjAfh6aogKAxDfzxuxV6zuDtw5gLnZuAb5cxY68WLNq6Wgh/mniGBYyuUh4p5NssEiM0Yn3RFf4g02yLnDO/ki8EzAW@L/4VzJrAMxglmbzMLJzmCdEEW3CkUIZvMYqqXBDTGRaIt7kOrvJRvocqwBLNZZgaaLzgghwwE3cmwRqORwYQNjg@8ctSaFUaoZDINKDem5mmynQqCmN0hKJCykXnCOluNGU@YQXjNkBwZAb2eiKomZiqNu5BhY3aXISwETmBfvGg0K41ZE8G94fTIzDJ3CCcE1sjMmm/gvUEwIZ2QuPsGUKk0MplmBTPEQvLqyXZ4JRWpcFT2DMsEdQBP3Ky/c5uxD0W1Ina4lIgE47HxnlnExogQHcKPM1tBceg/dNJviwi@QVkFuTAevkMC6Q6XUTECwJUkWZYZ/HD5fIfdhuAZB5WhbOGR4RAy1CKoBUQeDGeAMkKG6jdDL5B/orH13hcCw8Jsbm4KiaaYFw9lIp2iMPekRicXcDMfaiA1JpaqInobdIwjxAXS1yn/zSQuiyUZB8w@zPDf7dtb7EMoJj0XfgKTMnmn4CQ4lO1MRtQAftPJCM9BFxGgnRKg14I8a5C2kxGyWcbkRgLD2OHhYYAEeTxvCBlo5lpexXdcDJpOpwlIIctZOZsNnjI9yUMOHDKFBk95E4lLXw5mmlaog8pUZ@jF4vqNCnover558wZqhXZH1Q5AJWXBRimtUKFA8OBGJCxrHh730QpVgavjTC0VGEvRXClcaZYWWIptpQW@p54jEV6ppFapJCkeUF9ObYX75koqNQecJ000EdHw4lpjpZgOA/cO2d7hw4f7j44m7TYTDPoSstGZuE7P8LwUhu0@usvPU2jVUjrRaiHoo5qGDEbYr@WIGR/cfXLwtMZ4oYMqSBFidVoVDYpZVYXEZPLpdiLYNyTiV74c8Snea4uypbRqHpImmkKiZ6BmgcvdddovUhceesM7zgw0/awoZtUSqnNpmh1mwtecKUMblNxgBfQpPGUhb28TBYTmuUQrD@iE2ioJzWaw446pQvPp/hEkODpkqpaTheZnbCZjhtKF0LQalmEP/dEmbl0Tj3NirEybrVwW/7R8Hu5qoZRVi@X2xoZ1LmGex1Rt57gH8QJezyUsxgdwMeEDgX0AXnBBHrixkAW7Og8O68HWOrT2lOL760S1CN0sLRxDRXNwwmRxAaLQupfXcYTExuef@6zZBKVaOrgnJIBbjFi4u0wy@/JIpmruT12DQoeM9c1PTPx8m9w3vYmlz6HrADUSFxcXA4B0cI9pTY1eeYo@3i965NMF98VMFxJ2rdZ4oxbKgnZSq73Ja5oAHsKWgtvXNqAB0C6ALYX/1T3IJJ@vKMCpVFGERz6fF3B2WBBqhsBoq8ebXKMh8TaYL6i000PALwLos4YWXUHc2YeLuPkcj4shEMCGvstyYViZhwVvJYHegGi4t42@P1sPOmfu1q08zlzkC7loioJKzC6gbjbzhTxSXPj/r@WLVmi2J818Tt1WJuDUwVnYVnRwdsFZ3Fa64DTBWd1WTHBOm3k1t61MmwITtrnhR4Z2JRqib8zQziz3E5ueYQ1kPCLUECkDTdwODCk3w4TNfqPv9Ohj0fW@bOJHu/E4KE9QKIh1x0aTZA00TkAHaFkqfS4MG2d0aFUwGkMZrVy4tm4Jfbnr9Oey588tPGxjOW4jCXJhMgxYQDdAIMGZr518vlBrsbY8cSY7glYsZ1pqDkYS/KmVrJbdMHbK5Vpf7lmG7u4Ua8VKto/neIJlq51irjaUP3v44L7vT54YdLhnp1CFBGgXCi247FRqxWK71RLFTIuyaeM3cDmfkjY2oHMbel@C58CxfU/SKm1I3DfdRiOZ3MmrmqTW8rnKhbAgHNIcS9gUMGkGS5ZFup8HrKBmOzZwnVpWz5rnRIXaYDC42DrPLF4E/Vzib0CfC0nPds@j17oUi1dj06xkLgLBRx8Auc@D9bqaqBUrYr1VX7yXS2K9fSHcHht9U8czPce586upSsCdOdQEZHTMhIua6zh@rWsMHNdYRMyrpTAiR@hqhIJ4EWV3nMMcz69mV4pFmp1fhVIoihdRqhAt4eIC6M6JDf2CG/Vs0tbXllottPeBFbXa26G5T6ybxPPnut5sQiWfF8paoVgoavlSqVjWYMipFkrFCnSzXClX1DQAUKhWquULaNFCQtelZiOv5QVNk7S8lFclNY//Nzg0/H/3@Br8a3iHVHlNOEKbGY9gLIPx12YP8Oy977AjB7@@MmR3jN6aGHsjnTYJ77mO5/094tzR7RMedNfkhiqjoPs6foLKG5v@aE2MZ5Mxmtsw3H80CPvjLiCIrIlHuAM313KcVRHK7NnjNaV8GJmGBmJw29AQ/cnBR/ePYs@j/d29@0KJ3Tl8dPfSoxhEKrIH@/eOotcyDw2TFiMQX9t/8ODya/AoHD57Mpg6Lv6Ee4fPCotb5IVnUIUCXMuRIm8CEtzwlaQ9GOZBOyqWQ4cq4MmFW6Cx3gqcxdLCmUPnp/yArelFO@n5WeuacBSeutUZcr2uwXrcqgqq0GTxLBCw1XJVECbMds5YOcf6jmXp@D3twQZ4jnQ8QWiglGnR5@Ax6zPHtfpnZt/YEB7iYcWqit8uRiSE@wBkPO2ReSGQMNB@Zh@/dI0rSF1rarApfmV@jSc80AudrjkcwXh45oQRhK6uM/i97wXpjfjlX@/h8zzI70qIdTW6kBBE8b7u67cTlVbda0@auVrt1i31sStW86I3NPZn0F7ZM@g/ujvPVkRfFu8xuZMY4kqDVVILzqSpN0EzaIEcDYPoTkEzmpVc8a9/@8d/9ye/XtUa6tZxbi@3vfPwQbEGrBEkS0bCYyBgyqRqaNVKsVLNa5VspVopFNVSsZhVtSxoaeUqCOo5taKWKsWqmq0UqiAQFKoQWqyWA/FUCeVRZasGYO0efkp3m7QVeQRqCV8wZK9Sepol9Oh9ykQD0ogCKoY@HcbeMhswljE1x/JlBhB11mOJe/f2cvfuieIdfMHNE3s5UezjS7GSy5XviKJBIXsVFG5Eh6epoFEy0ecvudydPVGccgBoz1sUR/iyX8IpLlE08WVv9949zGeALxqmh2gnPIS/WOFLGaLZ@AJSMwF4GUGDaLs8nwIhuo8vmCWG3OMhexAmih@F6GDIEx6NA7gflnR3VxQP@MvuLobsUbGLHNGv4MsuXaLowgu0fFEcgmPoQp8TxS44sf2LYg9cvbkOfvjZYjT5bPu6KM45eZBAojij2HrvRBQ7oT9m80mATRGpW6MXlZf6Nr1U8U8UtRBpjJaPXvKiWIheClC2@/c/0Ud@3xjya@7yZw9Kev9@Xjdn0/173Y8@6g6HXXe@u//REwza27sPgsF86naH3SBhtwOXA6n27mv6yXh@@YJSH3Q6Nd1aGfSVTqeg25eCOvOOgRhCqpeAWXANMaNxZw@C9u53buur1nMJYAe7/hieXbzujOF5R@/yoPCiIHrOul2xjs0fpXZchMWeeAJc1M6O9Z7r1PF91thgLJlKZuetUq5dpwA2Buk7V7/A8EEK7zpOxaTP561ZI9duzBplje8FGqTE45lWNMXsxnhHrRZrG/qOqhUysxqagnAGSZaU1B2WUm9tvWKpR@kdDSRx8XhnRxJbantHUyu1Uvn51lQU0zW87@TLNYiYS@YYw1u6VW7vlIuxJOVyRle0Wrmcrl8APXwYy7s4RdJJpc4M/SSdRnRRYYciUFnZnMpp1gepWXbW4Hixebo@a6h1buWU5a7A6qNJ7WnPd1wOcQjgZju5Gq6Cp0S1WhEhf0VJpdOoSZOqrAiL7ZSffvXo5OjoM@CETGgGEwmP@RfA68HrR/f35IPD8A1NYcv3UPtxXHkP2dVSCLfUHHodgR4g34fBE3Sq0A8P3LmOJe/TRjVQocKA0MCpHJillI/uL8F5OnLOeM5or6BOts3snsHQUrjZZ3qjCS69z1KEFdPTZzRsd5rNRqcxpiP9UMQw1VcYmdFegDnwOO6RFQVKfo6H0IKATiN3Ue82ZokZwOk0mKS@GDv9F1qmV@@jgfA7jTuYuN6BZ7duNAzXdVwxIdYHO3aDsant6QPjseGifZCDw00QIvBkWmrAjPQmO97H2HuoLVxITZfZC8weTccpEMe76WWv2CuSJvXVsMjndFQS90hc1AcNlnqerr@EV3eTpfrynfROod5P3WGdNPjkXgxeDJjGSoU6fbk3hZCgExFtsMx6utH8Csg9HPBJrQaIBHV8AjAxJwBr9ilAT0/Mi3qvYbGUxGYsTeQp1IeNFqZ@jbdtSRTbktR63RaakvSp0IR@Wp8n9IY37dJXJViuq2q5Un0Gfmq5UB9BxerPZ3W3MZm6Rt2C12BWjZ8I1etATqAagHn1OvX2l76e3paKDe5XJ1CvLRA1OnKnMavbaKcOmkQj34CATKuQy4IGDbdyFoZ5rZRVS9l8tpCVyugLY3y2mAVP0GpApEhZKZExMZub5WQ1qxpqNpV7YfZfpLMnKRBViGQsnfWdfXs6ZuADlYStkl7hqbN0RtuyGNSCw/RtiZopcIo6FgxoPmITMztCUE8M3aIU6bTE8lspazOFcTaPppP9VrtW259NvgpBKenlTilTzmVepdP11Ea64RkvhWZdaCJXoVJPNqDNBhOOzJuOW1DH4FLLWq3V6mIRy7lsPpeH0pmd18NtsSm2s7mNkgpVdMFIPGKcY8Tn4FDIWfhNOihtWwZUnVrV6oJME2L5iiZVleJWMccn5XhKYRKwNaQkSx2L4ennVDJZ1pLJdLKOywEbYjD/C7yM@FgSmGrylrojgvwl1sSqhhEWLJEOuOZC7EACuxBw8oEVqkLiXLg4v9gGVVih7ZMgL7INckly87aQqDEGYuBxYG9J2WDsfXdlZrabz/nzGDfWA1yBDMqCBEq7pQwT1S/2CZ7l32FJQEx3xy1Ny7dbWhkGMmCOYVRQwuu4ApLArftyEyjsnQN@25kmHoP7CpvP9YwUTsnfYmyY2RSozInLq527jd3hk916@LaHs7zHIF@L9aSYOE8mkhfwJyRu09k7jZ@9Y4nY6Ts@y/8LyduJZDKJ0@lAqDcJ4hFs7zyc/arh981Seo1zhFY7/eaRaZ1X8hKflAAWdXGR2FRwrTNYpsgXSukq1VR4BuorLzRoJAnbCT1AL8L5Ixi8ikWcuk4oLybe51ol//Dg0L7r3jMYPxJVKXTEZoLlVAlPFtVrgW9R7GycqNBG8mL@JJtgtxO0QV2sVjRR4x71BDuRkmqNH6OaPK0@Lz@vPH/47PDZ4T0hcbzxesPBVQoW0o@9sT/@KkRM5gtJxo4biVmjUA820jWbkrqtocmzMqsB@x@oJSn3usmbeZMCShqEvP2l7xdm2xV413IqvGtaMaM1m@qWxtKJydsvfx@t15zvf7L7gCVxbvvv/uRHWvnv/uRf0y695AXNd2v5cgJiolMtlRPn55Pz8wu4eFgx0U5wpArlNLj52ouaaCqqlrdtu85qiq5vlTMF7bZdV4K4allNJzwpEawilYsJ73UQpOUqEBQu85CXWMIqSew/MYuaent7B4qzky9o9Q1oRmp0hJNFf9uGV00IicrDF68Zg5desz8cmhq5FIXV3khs@420zd7gEssbaYO9aDRxqV7Fg5/hEsQWHoTDZbhkM6NsJRmoRazZuqhftDO0igHa43PD2LKPL3WC4w08CrHstWXDn7Hl0R8mCj08eA3fjK0vPDG1lVaUfj8ykbZtsGITWsWWArhthesQ/E@SjtNvf@k3Na30d3/ya687rzufaaBIVqslVUv87GfbU3vqGf3mzyDhNWZJQmWQFnHQfgg6IiWScUuaZpAqcsg90F@nNkrNPH6oUqISiTKHObSNPqmUwinKSVSRHW4Zr5@iaFtotSBLUjdZokrXBSGSTkmqdoe9LMFgW2hqEXq6cC58gEEwGLMGMGHhgwUo8BjD8Ov0Op41dSd0cCRF6dR2lt2CJJDDB2h0cIOsLQScXALup2xdTcpR9ohqJFOxseF5aMIQBiHhA0gSmKG15myio2EQjGnaMHTIGIXwpIB@C/JuQ94WT9Ah3xSVnkfIMo4dT2SD5C18AMIEUcEEGYOZ2xChDmzpAyAAlCEVADbbbJvl0@zczGTqC/uIF7gxHi046qFRAgGTIbQ@GsEIE9cxHniBxI8fPsR2EdQwiHcxzxAIh8GX1BugM2ByekOhjayGvDMogEUWulJUNHbr1gKrRsPspxmVCOGfmBOc66J6sFfjCsBCfevDfk3MMrQ8WQ99o2YHFM8QutDqJG5ysh5LykR8vRAE@H/nRost8lJVUUAdCxDUF@8VPSAZJEay8zrsse0GU7VymkXI9wD3HiFFZ8MjJfJ49qGsfRYGXgCGP0uEnxUBFnUUnz8M2u1lqxQMBtEpftMBbZNxZhBYk@DWx5DVHfhh6igVFMW0KPbAdEHBobX@0PBhKq@mMdnCUCThQXvbtQLuCteKaXxQKozN4KmjAb8gnw0yPNRzoEK9iWOTxT@ySITb96FFAI8KjKVxtKf2GX4DKKgbShzHyCNDadjyEWOyYEgfT6a0uNjedUELDmmTZcZQZr1xn2lVlqKGRkbd7AhcmhIRwl2QlpHGXcsYA0pPDYNOcnk1RRmCsDXtkmW7hya0q9E9E8Yb21OC71QrZ@aJqRzhNwwkZ4AHvridkATKZ9j9@Lp@YEXOcpwTZpknBp8WTi1ZWfEY6Asg8maBsosfELaGG0a0fJblIDjLY8GvDI8yd1aysbQbqXn66jOvbqQ6WKOvafAxXfwG9alux@hL12shUJG9uRfaaSJrQ/AuRyzXCCy0NJJoeyEyPSQEFqcaZOxIxuWGSQoU1tBSEzqFiWucMlR2BRxjgGn2Qpsn2IuhtB/QAEB9D3oWGnD03Rpa6gFM3H6qB10vYPA2@5DlNQEjcjNagckrgIFV31iGDmGQFMvh@X2oGJnm2JGvQO8c9yEMbUQEzQ/Th60b3WRcc9G82UYADgcdyqvBeLcIX4qxF@wd2J6p6BsQWAIMV2CykRIzADYjpkUOOkp/OTlv7QLxkhq7CinLEEJAaoBCokL4kXoW@1iPAAF3dI9bdA/MO56dnclkc3TqmrLh4QdsPMfWLWUyNEGidhTfGE@CT4Wa@InoAO7CJfHvVsmT0WRnhqJro3przp@CMPAawbabVHLgJXFwPMXvswzHZJ8MDYN51KDumfRtp14q2AXE25/Wzp6H7a@G7U@qJC8QCGMIZpadZ3tZAJbt9k6yg7N@PQg4pQ4JwKEWjdATLQG74cvYC13mZBDFcHzko1FQ1zqhBVSAJPIp3UXWvIRhzHn4GrxPzBkkso0ztuu6@jxF4WmMjQ04NSexh81h2KcQcMIww865WVpz1pq3l5LPouQwqEXbB1w0PiacXw@U2yjG8BkPn0H4jIfPFpmG2bZmbS6SodcFFgdbPdqsDGMimHkY54Lb812EEGSQvpnKQWDM@ZLfBfx6DUod0pu/QT02woYBbWICBDdSSuv5ceu4bXvG2VY7owyhsYtECKhxAN1qE03P@pEbqW@dWhPHW/Ky0VQpjEoB3ujVGwWtgbcVLGNUQdQwOL1MtC45HAf7HLhAEBQYIKAcBoEoGuz6KTNdj2xiUyA0nJa4oDFHrBUg0ybpKwgK/EBc4qTnhI0DascAoX9UJEATQljYc/jnykLu8KnrQJwwrkRfWBqjlbNkOwmUvNRVOK@pUyXFsJKkEE0gO4qrjctFCcOhKlqXgmLFvAjqP47@xnujP4B@sRp7arB8wKgL8a6CewxBhAi6C1GVNRuxegUMlC3dMlwYufa5fBqM1pDNlhKqGTwfLIJ3ht9gT8Uqv5fm9UPHF0VbrEVNYd5oQBHnDd4teb8IScoJHiXzgmTzsCEE6TkDARi5lcmMINksnmzWaHDGwWZrkp3FkJwRkjOehMeerUGyHSQD7ekgHF6wetogneImSBHgqXwYBTFoIjL8EDuugH@BFhhx7TTIc8FzqBUEbQhFbGxnvfbK3FsxpGNM6xIAbIhXAPT5l09rwmWGp0rRW8SjOClDHsXfgmbAeQU0MGLBdW6lOBU1MtKBQeAXMzQOQN8VMy1BVGleGP9y/CdmQ8/wp171zC3HVJc9c9lLf/8onm2kbKyDxqQPNVdAhoyazDM7MO8ZlzkS@JHwkQNSXffMYakVwjb4K9MgqdK1nK4y1nEnC34PkfvKk3k61B9wTYXdnji@7juFQo0rTSY1u1X5c53BHNoOfkYlZqkcZL2@Y3h20odK7TlD2/SMLEMjkidGoHYYwacThLicHDgdTxCCGU2uxiJo3q5Q1O108AvNnU4Ktw2ma9FmaNpFiM0zmRRQ/wVXLD2wpwDo4STldL8wen76Zphodj9IdmT2TlKHkyAQZ193GfCwHsj/EDoCCYZ5zkJzJJPeKEp3/RR9S2TkjJ0hSH1TTxYw9SXwBwvYiJA@mRAuWaajSluLfXyBekmql9XTQdKvvHdS9hUtpaej9NoygCViZJl7mcZIWXdFdp212fFkYX5P3x/fp3F8n16PL2nhl3HmqnmDB75f1vnUAgJEXKCRvxkNLDrwrf4VdJZQibxRruIJ3hnFPu0U6yOmuxB1N4guD6B9ZKM3D94ixD9ZR//rKzBMvv@u1afjZ@ufzoHfjHEHZIq@fOWFi6MpiH6QRt5zNbuoad99x7wgLn508B6KECDGEuOy0RoxdMwJqN1eNF0cAr6hzePmrCvtnnZsNXjgCpzc0yw70dZX0d1O37D0udFPBTGzMbhhiZ@Awkb86t0KjoyOmJ7Ddb0UjF3pKBSGcSQ6j1Rb02T07Gk6vb5Z8Shm1HpoppwwPFhPPwy/wppxiq/BZ6tBD0gmEzgde2ri9OdkPplzg/cW//5RwEf5@MNrEm003EwQoAMfPdXsItv0dezzSSoq0juMCFFcebnIaI86hIj2iq7W4fuR6OaSQuXGEjXCWhaWP/WyusbN62o81irCNslXmd6tSd7U6N65zcWaGge2YGF77zeEXIGM@zl6vVQcIve5tsYc@wpPQD@ap7PXjCqdFQw1SkmczjdJ3Sb5Ii2gZnwAT5xw@gSeCHBo@B3eoMKy4ZxW8CVBRiFjfRKTWgIfENIBSoyKnOQBGrFYQuiG6OcXUZ69tXn2ruTZW8oz6gHLWcYiCb2lLINawOq5rgosY@Cv4c4YhLozPK5j23DZju7ibMV50kzWzCxLniZrwJCTRrK2nwKmnOwna3fJ4SVrT8lxkqx9BRyLvpV8nayF3QIjuPBKjtvoH7BwfO8la3up9IXg6yeGF@YrJ2tRnUKcHf5KFAFSYLlBasQlNtsJium7BgxsJFRmGbYYL4vqE83DZOmXg3/@8Sb6rAsG4hznFkVmGaYuDRqxEYPnA8NG@NmAFT25Fozm@4f3aD9UFAWzyYCOF09D4EEMTySXmRFHDENpRQOegCDyzdpqjFhsJHtHdILcoYVSJS/nT9STSR7opyi8BZHbi0zoi11B@rC@lkHwCnw3PDHxOjyvoBNmRxjhmmx6BVpI1BfJawqFdb2MS1D78Rqiue7lSICtFEbhtURgYzwdZDhanMPMJs5kuZFQKO63N@NpaFKOd0psvZeSEVcIeuaaYPIOSoaMId7509cVJ5YOUVtiQRjYyrV5L4vGBeLFGLTgdTFJlXc@QCHGc6CHG70T@hra3cBJ8Ti7ydJYsW4YCtPyLIlzLbNJSCyj0aup7vPcI@V1H01hvZ/6Gqac4VxLCgHEUka5cP7qvIf87nD5PRSoQyJcymCVYL16KL0qXl87yl7C3Fpke7UCMTDL7qZXCkdRDguSg3YQk8yva2tXRHzc8sGFfJ5pBP2StB@SLdIJbqDbZd2Cw0IpwT1d9jzRwPNEW0@oqxKJdSqHQouMOQVweMEjTBdFux5XXvBVVYwhNL@tW@9dwe5yBccrD@FRAdxLJOe93J3atMtl0beBbXMfZKlqjXFGTsulUTUvPIHd09JttGwLHoedJ3cPHz34Ggy65XI5HYzR8wV@2GtxrjUaxzlk2lwdjQcr1BYti58swsVunI73Ro7rbxzb4hVewpk1CAM65BI2v6CPpwNeFuPnl/oupONxYxQNYJ0suoG@xJVQ1NFxyDYDuvpAEMNPbekBkFC8BXpnSVtL08d5Oh1bHxudDg1fnQ5uXup0glEMqyZcEU//LLGhTD2XvkTMvyx1Jghk5oHdPWSf3t89Ykf/b3HXutTGkqR/009RlrBRQ@uGDcYWwhYgbM1g8CCwjwOw3Egt6HN0O2oBkm1OzO6PfYHd//sI@yrzDvNrn2I2v8yqvgiB7fFGjCOMuruqsrKysrJueXldVTtHW39WH/aP1PvK3iEs/N8ebe7WthT9r@7Vq8pKaF0iCh82lETXba/pIbSqWi4UniiGvNUfTETuZLZs@V53u@p1v@nhmmo9cLsvL@Ql1/NGG1KqStvRCc4wfY662PVH0LfgMIG0jcXipsU2grAFUJT3jPa0Xex5u/2W3/Ypr4W978D3AmNWpjo@9SDJW2Pl7MgiCREBWXWII31CA@uairuUH3c3BMYV/SuQGDkkhGArpzThwn8/TMHD6sGbuoKziK39ve3aYW1/r6529g/o9e2H2t4rometfnhQ2zxCEmd8s79d26ltVfiDIFDIKXhx@PUyGN2LQg7ZmSrN33DznRtQ94dvyVNvrODVtcvWkoFauOxB@vhux//stRZK1mWA5QssNPmqQGXmKwev3tGcr7zfccNproJZ/yB1FHCUyvmCWufaaLBs0Hgr6eFK0162aPN9RHeiEKjGK7F3hww/O8oAZyWelu@p1BZ0VHD2LU4geCwb0FTRA4INUEZhpaw4wNTCgrPOIDeotmanDzedUpsoEeoXFH1pVE1KFlNM68oAKOwdaj2cBxVL4Qfie/qwrKsdDSWDehx@kAzqiXzAUrQG3RG1onNcjvYvIZ7Vqnz4tTvY4Wth9TT8sOnyLnZN4yT9xl3qqjBAH1xidDiMmJzycKhTN2j6PhcJOD9CbHU6MjA8Ce5IMlGuElm3jXKmSNi0cdWg1d4kZjJSiRugJ@S2R4HKlO2cOoRykNfzJYDbecftiQpUpLrDvKfW4H2ovKGXD2HgM7YgGfSZARF0MYlHWG5brwq97y1HJTdv1ehqHUkOPmpU0L6FwOYtBP4ZMAQom9jpNHmmYgNWgOm3NStngj5xJM5t/4jnJ3ZuXTa9RAGttZX51f/82dZEdhL7JKOnyNhRF332hrSs5KvMdn9IY5zFKoeKghRsXvQHI1/6MJNsAd848TRHuTGxUW2fDHF1baDDdI29fi9W6Rlx8R21nhFTfk@tzPFydx6KryiGMHE@TcKidwd03LP@lRe7O3NwiXTt4fiFFsJ8V47Dz8mIMZH1pxXJjj8UQo@ulTe2N0@yf3xyEH9UxIKE/zVKh/hPjIm6aHjwPR8rLA6x7tIjzcSNCy7PUFrr4GlpiVFugNE@8MKnfd3LRilME3Xj299hYzP9nT9@/VqWUllIJh0zOrjIRNLNUcemSofLnCqtAhKTnYQsyfqM@eIwzFBev4RdDXoB7nR6kCPYt09FZdMixLTu7LJNkkUHx9XdHcK31QZrVESRxWEvE@@P/MfMZnlpw85HCiUqRs6MEdGOgVy07ZhaCs9Xt8Bt3w@O5Pf3g1u7FzuZHn4I2va90H4It@zS3bBkWorB@n6wf9wDVia3fwostd25G7BMkrehhZweMqcznw61ae@v8dOtvuOxR2Aw9@IEJQQaq@2yx1fUxit2RgrYcTDRgqh@uF09OFAp2Z9QWZJ72DK0tBgE7AfqbaRt6/dY2OXCRVO4WQ4XT@ZLQqPN/LtvMM8k3h2iQq9BHE2PUFhEwX3a/liknp5ZeAnB2vcsEA3lkth9MTIoONaAb2gPSMhGnRZroDWzmWmZfPwgrgSu6ebI2jiuw88a1jJ3I@TscBIHFNcJcs9hWTK7/97L@vi5qUcWWHA9hAa3aCVN8w3tE@pU8YAy5nLJHrynW0yXQsleFthpQzsofhWSK@yfZyhmJFmEy1o4Jtb14lijJuvjebPMYYVETAMuND11omg0U4IR8fxlPd6hdjTpZZJTEC0yEYT0ZZwrqPjpjZ7CmBrhPFkOF@TxsTbP2BwbLE9xOqthl@7O9BC60KvT4mG6KpK291aV/f@pSmaJRE2G5jMbYxIJ8urKyuNvwZ5uhSme/VnYModMy89Rd0D7@whkMAn4eJ84t7bnmPSIAe4hnajWmwEzVZCWOjPmlETbeTKK40e4yLkQIQOn8YjrOl2rrcZTuM2GLjNSHDpnudWG2BAOGyqj5hb1b@6vDgL5m/U9@PH6ZLAhE1QHb6CV/6Y/DLzIKi/m2yX2CdawyW/ecNjjbGLP1AWUDJsx3Wtsx9Z2ovAqrUIi37fFW9LW1kmiduuYswauhI8XcwjljNO90vTxXrZYijd1p7ZbVYvsRLKdOItMDVN2TPY88Hv3IcAymM8lMH2wDd/D4Dn9JxwcA5LIxNZ8GaaN/U3cmCK0aj7muEFaLVTL1uJ077eDptuDSxAn9TBQKecRFeRT2Or@jj3rZL1QSpQn5IJBL0OlnFQ2l@Ki9A0HuoCUBCG9ie@xCQuWGkZTEuY1533oR@FiyxvL6RlrTrr54lph9ZnFres5I6d7/OzUWWyWU4omX7fXDS6H163fzvsXV23VUYNfz8bNyefflVp5oh5TXcuPxJNvcbWcZ@epT@nvmnpWYM7VCL5gr8QILZyTmKtKLahoH156oCT6CG@an8NCYopL1WLXcCFM7Ebl7vHqablXLpS6x73TEoz8Rkvl0VJxKYMPj2gWJRkjN/PHo1PMqfFTV693peAvk2N7atMQxaYh9OWNO/T7u5W9V4nTOCwAcASmdb35QF3COM9Bmw22J7med53Rx2SOAsdaWCBZc2wVVISpPJ8n4zim5RNm1CsOrWaDMf@d2NZcIXc5GPU5xThFBGupr/5Xa86YMRX4RIGyHPvGdSLsCwhOlCeDiyH5OhEt6mxRlmtF2E7aMRDHKMniMHWSSsGmEIhqW67jUyvIeW7zAkggbvlXLqbW1zmKObFakONTPKhyuEM2mCic4hEXIPQz4NsGVMEr94DNPixqPt6LeJAvfEY1YjsZVpC3eKWIFKh/qy9s38Tl14kAQvg5WXPl9BGnXnnRQlJsB/lwAV7Okht/XDPArFI6ZQ6NBWyprxwBZ01xphGq1WSi73PXIKfQiv7pFmSL/HarGWF@W7IzSfieWr8FoCV3KSdt4KcTFcvEimVNMZM5Roq5b1IDJ120PXrj0bCaqC2v0yGkhRZzETnwyPa9uv6lsP7gGHWehshLevZWejaRnpN0QSrKlaMJPsr0PJ4plf4S5btRqSibc6uusuLFS456upmjJUmUt3Rf3iA36jf8KPNG2JXClWHCeiIhG0v5OKP3JeVBokzI4GH6saRr/l7WPR9imcj7Mlk/fi3dQR4rz2pdkykuzfX8zgtLh7zWKWCzFFFTKSnOUQ2VGVRlbYOpxQmt4HDOz8N2oxxBWSoaicNjJrWx/jKV04uMF5lpNMSK8dbAmjFGYlTiOpeYcGM2WKR6OPlBDATDBKMpM3I3TOGJLjyJgUWuB6ZasYK8NcCpadNDvAy7yK/4YwZ7EjmTLz07cU4wH0vjxbo5SSAWug9Ss8mUlCYwF5GPulH3zCJR3ZNpiLOFxF7sFDis0xMb7DaOwR@EciIuKIykuEX3MEVTOspQNOx7Vxci8cb6R37ReuXSGnvQ8caqgm2Gy1ZYVsLAfeQFowC@odjFTXA5GHRw68gLvms2odZuRZZXcN0SQYzN7DmrBs0eye/gSRukU6Gc2gfkayiIRAnB5fk5jMlgAdu/hmjFiYs/ylmV3kQONGjMPF4WM3NPwfkGC@COfx5HQnpORg8oHQzcppezaI0W0OrHkqa2fR0NlM/TYTcC72M0pT23rL9c@s3ftl7hPvdpsfC4GCPZlb4OLuQeP4kMrIhIJmEZngNXik8sK3Y33JS74SwAOmoXE/074k3vyuv1PKtCMwZnDGjRGnjDK6@Vs6wDL7wEBlywMm4mYYfdvxw25XCHFl0uMSOshANHrsOIw/CL@Vmui5t8V@ZYuLSKbpupq6/8FghoLE7afdwO84UF3AQIPVCo642IKIu2SqLEd88aF167dHEQRdSAn5PY3URIhl5/5DepZ/gky@oQKLkGiSrrtaYwofqaHRfGwblZCMA8JqKAQcBcJd2Hg6UvzX8IB6UbZu7YXdMzeZJ@fR4rNNy9oU/SNyIw9woXi@FOHXz4ulZX9f2dw/eVg6qi57cH@@9q29VttfmB77hxUc4ueNXr/V2SLuFtutya79OHVKVOJVOcYFX2PqjqL28PqvW62j9QtTdvd2sEjcAfVPYOa9W6o2p7W7tH23z7ThDU3v6h2q29qR1StsN9h2s1xayonNrfUW@qB1uv6bWyWdutHX7gGndqh3uoDLf6FfW2cnBY2zrarRyot0cHb/frVYWGWdu1@tZupfamup2j@qlOVX1X3TtU9deV3d2phu6/36seKFYSiLVys0pYVjZpC4uauJ3btYPq1iEaFD1tEfEIwV1H1d9Wt2p4qP5SpeZUDj44Gmi9@pcjykSJarvypvKKGmdlvkEV6peto4MqvCWBEvWjzfph7fDosKpe7e9vM63r1YN3ta1qvaSs3f06E@yoXnUUohpy1QSDqEXp9Lx5VK8x3Wp7hzRnHL2FvoNNnfyeCENYVqjoNhMYahBoLRFp/@ADoIIO3AGOev@6St8PQFOmVgVUgEbF1mE8G1VIRDyMN1PtVV/t1l5V97aqSN4HmPe1etWmDqvVkaEGhYwPxDpU6RG3Gv1EeMkjMatlONfh7lS1HVXZflcD5jo3cUC9prmFybb1WtM8Bx@9sUMUv48zA7cbP1hp3/505cE55e0TmdlnNKHHpK397SrNyNq1VSpKOKJZZ23KlVI8jWaaMJFeEy5rWt7Z5XnD77X7sDENi8nBRzc4dxC2x0bMkxPrnuhV@nyFC6TTjca7SoM2uvVGw3a@p2QCjW@V0Mfg9@WydRsRCgE7bxz8PH8udF9PEGrjkb7oZEU9XEAgp1D/kai@uV3PVvl8y9PFYLwPwOboKJBrkwtcpZBoZGNHBGuJquSTCX73NTtwwYwBn2s2cE4KzUjO1A/oT@9r9CKTQ@wDSWc57srnsYllNPzPnqlGKmGXCPxHeyTw21xlLvC8384zhXh12PPnzvv9Vsa2TRnOO6J94HnG/kbxM@98qnh2ujwjy9fOOopAYPbdvIQJ7581yZTul9yQW5bBn8aIf2yDjfh8wKkpV8WH1frQMvNIikMjyVHatQXMK7iTseZ7U/ml9h67ucLyk9LU99fhdxlb0BeEE1ua8I653Cn/vD6VDDTA2BcHkcTXHjLy@VgZo28SZr6mjBfIdO23oPlDc/WFx/M6kYQWspduJ14nZuOhP45jT3L41UHlzebRzg6JTmD7ZG3l6WrJCt1u/eLI7wfUw55m2evYgOZxWqdxUmyUbNHCh0dKzMN3xP7MwPk8MsJ1u@k0/gg/D6HeRlKTCYIMzQ0QuagHFb2UBzqkFDvgeGAZfp05MjUDZBJNtdGarjvmJb5LayXmAa3M0plwr43xB7DD4W@GeNggzUCaxdj3LnEu7S5Y7qV2jKoob27YcQ@y5FKGj8WNW0gDPupi/VlY1/Kb5u1YLwaiyojxyt3OJQmJB9NYKKNX0ZOR/Zb9jOgDYPYeRl9@0fxGjx@0gzt2d@cGo8qoTmTcCUvinDo6jNaNPtaQTxFGA07VTE3rCqf8tkaKx54@Tg4dg8RGA6OCGC3Q8U0CLoV@RKarZA3Ylwu2@iKcCucdgFPSHKvfiXNnNUdDKRn/IfrdeKVQAit0ciJUuw7rsEyWD6EfC0POBJl@ih4M/19Ikxnw12nHSdAjasWcAH4XJRmq0Iq2r0wU/9pcNMRuNyJqxj99iMDcxDvmImyYvr0Zi30NkUD3zsR8@MBuD9uZGQQAk@NgIz5@Q5W0C5e2Ti9Tti6Oe5JeszvIKD1XmKniFtzs6qnDyy7H3K3gxVa2nDXFKtylouqlbNzOeNTTlmlqK68eBikBZxv/H/lFPgAJBzxz6YVorU5zVkGPMiMHtKul2ITTCj0m0bL05s5bu0UVc5GZkP365ssQikBvAJ/b7eSYIn0l6rlJj4s8E6tD9oIHf@LYJmPy0S7rzlgRs@MBzsMWH4Yg7MjoGhNER6Czq74Imso8ZEURVBJpHUZ@BiFu7RyRlqfV6xB7PpkEh4bYH/XEkb0np1omR04cfGgM4@byOfXGnRDKne9rtrBYfrHed6C7iMrkWEKXR4iVZr8/pKWji3YTjo4/sXPqvT508HrB5VD7L6T5zB/qEwmz6KdqsGyS3TtPM@JDnlEL/BGsFVo55g9uUteDhqi4JxlnV1WGmNfw6IY5dPTHS0WVWY9S1okm7JaUibiuVtXXr5JLCKpdhnpMQT8INxess8n14N4hHH7X/eFvmPuxBOq1vFbomTQGks8CpZNqPfbx2BxJ0wf9gE80qCtwAhJSoigHaaGiKs3RTzU7ab2mVOQdE75LuSU/Xk/IpEZbiiqKGFfXTsy3mqXOBJWWtWvQ0FlocXmFUZm14bq5czPG3kKT19YqddILRcpzWUSUH5qlI55EboZPH/CkD/nLDwOMHvqCO269BAXCWLPiXvW2nGP8oFPw3veGrfiZKK1kWu4Ax2@89en3mBfN0aF2@9d0R4E3oR1AM@@P8wyjkflT/6LX2Op33HO/77u0T4Mb@LFIPDxO@BEddj7sXwccPYgTWrFMrUn0LP5lxA0b3sN7yVLMNVcw8gaZuJrCaDipXIibCD45hxJgFE6U@Xsw7SMtLPNkJSpkJe1PWR@vaJfuLPu4OKuw3OgDgBZwG1MaFGJDOmLDpJjxaelWhrP7MsRwPFNZ5dp3aOwlMH5GJOJrmATGBplbagnxRmBndifGx62x02IfhEM4WvK2PYTCCTL82XERoZmkyAtoCjxXxbVCrKjcoozhhxAPk7vJvfz0X4w9IfAT6Bcfz@KWWYzAIq5tvC0Fsl/RXkYJF1YP9FlGsyQmKeaf@72Y@SEHoRhPQ00mT@6iBmv@0KJIu9m7xZUYkRna@CDIXaZBIqcxsTGpLKgFm/12YAlSGWUKdzOs9y39WR78uMSVkzMIpi0NORND@i5SNYlKiIE7pV4bR1l8Kn97xCwvf2@vTRGwPEvlLBaLOZMyKxe2QPFlfsW1Vn9Iwjg1RT2t6rEQjPqDhe@k3p2yY6Zntlm0btr2NxWBhdnKNFkutpi05QkeJyVrGp8ppklSjDXNiIewfeXnkM2niTguNzDeyo3JN@hwF80ivalwUgn7uyVjH5PiFTR6zUQTDinGHU5KS@H34wY1vHG3BNEwZXvVYInRgMhoTOQxBmqKTCGVvp9CzH0a9yl6tIhyqLdFtIv3z51EnVaSMy5PTVLCySXoCcftMNokuTRoQ/kCbuJkhRsKqXDBOXYmfJVXzJ7ByTASBCBWxV42OoeSE9yos6b4iKMDtDMNaAsVIYnoaSOu4RA6/Q8Jxl759eGO1nhoTLLF05JAGoeQaFfBue6DZOzN6fW4MWYot0hBQ3wGKcIW3ZJNF9/fqp9tC@UjCFKak7Wmb8FBY2y1RNjQn3hSY4w1cFSVLpkYUcmB0GDRQGOBdinnHU@2q1j9@UPheGg36GFEGwj5nMHPki4Bd96rhZDaKDJuTZDF1uSW0War7IYUiRhK3kF@PRRlqcsbVwLgCcZUvlwkCHBrytjjUoBd78Q5L4Go7iMqWC5iWNJH9ooa6XnOSAdRdYYnK7EchVk5nsVhZGcCoYXF7DwRIrRmmZ0lgkIT3UxcYjmezm5PlIMWxIb3heLUFbpXkjQMe04IyDGfC3YkUY6LyiloDubEJyt2IjHkb059VoilFqZTiT4hhsfZ4nTqWiGRmqh2eTlZNFGS6GHHa00kEinsOMKhVPi5f2yaEnd5HuqExjYZiVWG1s9GTG7aZdK@LfdroNbZKNusMQy8uGW42X41JMRKwin7/Q7Y1QJfGcB3@0@31mimGkx0rAD2S2eMXTKyIeQVawpTPZqFna7xtBc6KDB72n5bvTvc2Um4fT2bGEWjrjdcKRQKYOKzuPN7o1uNoyS/n0/mzrcvO5384PpPw3dneZb9nschAZ6bHbRHXUKDIsj1h@cSGQI4UFbkzmpDVuz1L9vteAgG3FCi86jbJKf2hqB4AvJDpZd3h3wAxCD1BPsJDUT7Pqlw9F27stDUUMw1FJWGSvBVytyeEXnwoQ397PCmioFBMBttJpq37PLGF8wgiGzCncXui@0vkXpy6rXX6fQd9R7xh@EpYO5musDOTrxAQbLghpGtey8D9kfrKO/K78TsipElzusAZyYmE2fC@IWHb/wD77w6HmRSxx9TNK1Qk5fQzCX4p3ZU6jxla2fx3wFW@JDQ/q7cXXeQaTKdpjPTVK9HcPREGD0uOjP3PoksNp@JaZp9OzeIOhvdHDtroKbbvBYwvuy5e7kld2QPiZs6GRfboGFBYGic4HPl@0rA1OxfJxavRu3290lFDgMgHftDElEiofycQOQ7AB6BevgRPeFF@89ZGtY7Uw5FZIGDYB235Q4KNFDAsh42y79fZyqVipofLC2pSmWTHrJZVdmsqG182NxU2/S@ifdH5eWVlZLI3G37C33cNB9v1CbB4BPOpebFcJteKa0MuzFoa6OL5/Pleac03yivb5SC/HFlE2b99PT3f/uPv//7f@Yr@uW/8bLJL8cfw0y5XC4/3/wy/@imhPfj7dOF@bPj@cHpwnkJXPYP9hrer42ybqQ@mhueWWmZBWJfWY/U7LPZ@4wuqkxMwK47/I2ky3OVbgb5tP4aSOQolrHpphf77sGO8oy28CbowPRWnpBIE9AJjuOpd5oeFPBoviFKEi7QA5XycrdiDu7hDibMEN6qpLUnHl6zXnmwaYk8KcAWl2asrN8LvB5OwK94zSvNsyyXfv1RQ/Nv/uOb4HyzP1aLJxm1WFCLjlpMpfinuPqMvtrzeR/WuZKNtgOplEMp0dUC1AxV4PNCj/cPHGtnityWNc8hewDJuKngzGIF54S7PzaWkYBrwbk1h1CcSo5I@JIJRdJf5ns31C1fKMdNKmFqwwuFht7FcGWxG5Wwf7EEcgNRBIhq7gpBnvepStz0sUUynvLmi@5ri6MJMWCQ9eDVDo97fKC5aL6ndZ4TeymEOWL1efmKubEkxtCMNlKk/ggBvlCR7WSBLQkX0guWaHnHWsnNFCvsePs084muw8QbGd10KfSHijGBaHPHCTff03YtWpFbrldUyg@vV2JVpaZ1v5UVK9K97Iz8gTZX4NoxoL6Etd3ISEKPMiCBIz77n98eYXxQYDxFTXWLBMuaqFYfTZeR0NOm6dTBdk5ujmJEyH/M0Nj@OjW27TxbiRh2EB5gpEJVvrbrdwLtdWXIxD53h2eIDui2OaDaSO7N@DwP0VenMO63Q6RzDJlVzqPxTE1JD4buedd1VHqvfzh0JzWatmjlM2rmbGohXDABCQw@XfWs5hmEpUW6S5giYVNYcwjBCzoTHR5N@jYV2pygS81Q0G5XMAgS7MSU9L4m@mqKjhFX/0AnxFG@JbzD20gtYlnyQtNIQ0rFzWZ4mN0aOpapIT52woGTsgTVcGQaXtCFLjHRdvnilyR5Bz4CdN0pbQWoTRFWn6F@zE7nXs9NTE6DjmUM/fMlJfMixjOHohRtJMvESS1GEe@AFa0jPya9QMjcZNwZWXOZzNxJoMO5pePzCDv5DnXx867ywwB0HMCMLUPUUc8XYTk1Q0UxMHKqxpr/BKHdcc8Jv8m1OwErnqQzLx7k7eOPJ73TxcxJ7@vJZ5sx0SLZzLJZldaX2UZi6bFCM2PeSbwarbTAuBo86SUznPSU2LDESECI5DPHH/OnX/OE0EkaMelP0kKQRJcBk/z99eUBPn8LzXQSi3zamrMXbdP5mRdFW9Hcyr/oQ/lgyy9hYTaVfExP@5xhm0Cxne7vl2JyEuTXlgtPlotPaCd07o2zQ@8S8202uDzzxrSUCLCdpann5HOCGxKEuBkHbok@jqmdEtZEbE8CbaSkRage5lyPFbIVlckJT1B@ojK7S4WJix3mcXH5iA2/o4jlTF72BSWqgzHuy2D@DPpd1OMGkGvT1iHCkdAyEB0RPkLNArIJvnIXh9pmuCywnVNObcF3KwOh7s2nY7NFr9/L6sWanVsoYRENq5nOWmGtMD1Gbw3RxAid14uphQequPHi6d/@a//39Ci9sZx/P6TfUfr39OpaWh7pgd4em7er9EZ6HdlWb9KTPO2B6fHp3/6Hym/8ieAgZbJOfzZWDKzVSXojW@YiX9Mbq/RQXF6mev/3r3@lNszLjg2xWOcbjmLESoYiW26PeZfSVQ2tlG3pQiRW2DALMETDkPbm9ALFqPHyWoGP6dJaq@LK056vjD6KnuJZMWvEqkJykmH0KWhlJAXKqCArII0KRVvFdDeM2gaYN0JTfXqYWw1oB/BJq3OEVYaqGw8DqAzNy7aIOjAjNdJ@Xh42Ci9SoXrH85TRKSmZJSS2dlrWrj0u/R8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/7qtl1)

Installation on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install rc`.

`"` is not special in rc, it can be used to separate rc from other shells:

```
";echo 350;exit#";
```

Answer (score 1):

## 351. [AsciiDots](https://esolangs.org/wiki/AsciiDots), 15872 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  1111   \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                             _                                   # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11 .-#351$#&                            #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68)); exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #   wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c9tadiD4Y@oh80dcgXomKRIAAX6TImVZlp/12rbctvze60fRNEiCJJ5AgAZAibQsV3fPbm86ycxmejqpTieT192zme1spmqyUzubzk4yU5Xsj1Op@Sl/gPOxtZXaSv8HveecC4CgREp2J6ma2lpIBC7ux7nnnnvvuefcj4Ou7o1@9rMEXuyxY82HluMz3/B81nfNU8OV2Z05u62bXlHLCwLG2nWH07Fh@15NSDCVMUu3h1N9aLCBafmGm2WeYbCuYTlnEK4xtj21p57Rb8JbnjHbOGMHds/sAwTmOyeGbb4yXAgrMHbXsF6PX/us54zHut332MQ1bZ9Ci4w91uFlMO2dML3r@a7e803HhqASY89sSx93@zqj6BPX4InKDED1TijNckiFsYeO6xmQg9MzPM9Bzyp46q7pPNh99NGl@GqOfaQDUhPLmF3KXlXZp6bh9i@n0NgnR/fuXfbNs69Ijs3uXUVJLbDdqe8c@JfhF9nu0LB1pslVWbscWAJi@oZVyVVyS0EQds90oRb1oLZYT7ehVrDOtpgxnvhzJvF61i0rqkOP6R6belPdonj2dNw13DCi5@uub9pDdmb6I@aPTC9KR7G9id4zpL5hmWPTN/rMMiGRMwigAGi7z06M@ZnjQtUGMB3bmkNCo2cOTEwS4gEA8Ur5I4PDGetzqEzbh0bAdOYBGpYRQksLCYh/1@hOh8yZ@pOpzwC3vunpXQuAduesbwz0qeVnWRfCgJjkfzYy7KDRAjgZQBw5HKsvpoSasWjber/PctBeAY8Tg5lANUKrxvJ58GeOC1SDWCFGATBqv7yMxgzqBqp84NRYMZeD8P3IB7HVLc8JkFlGDQNt6JNUZwj3sesMXX0M1OgbRNNPDh4zr@e48AY/jMv7zXVgerrPtrdZcv/R3SRrRtUiu10hqqIGO4cqSISB7FS3ptBC4jXhQP24UWoBqyy5kayxJJBFy7FCgRWge1aYVgQiqbkqOKCfa3kVfiWmVVhBhZ5STGYxn4GrD03L4FCGCKWMDVwrMg3uuQLLqxUec@hYAx6tR5mVWb7CSmVWLrIy3KusqkFuCLrA1GoRfiX4AbQqoKLCL1/ggBbtHtoptrU9NtDHpjUPoBP4HiuqrAwQAV8VIGsVgADPfB5/efgRWstXHLY/AmqP9FMAL1nmCXIdI2I8WIUKPJStLYU4H7JWnr03wuyBdEC0YoWVIfsSUKIAKABltQpkX8zxgngjw7KCZCMPkxG25Rz8APMy0KEC1M8BLXNIzDL84B34mgYMTANupQED0lTw18CdxywgXgnCSlCVpYBeI907gYx4PlqfiA@cG8CoSG1kVioSCSBAbbE81FmJFaAh5LEhFPMM8AdcyiUG/KqiskqBVcoM6FnNMagbFfDCVqICn1QBHxWBQf2r0ABUwEkFaqsAVM0XmRAjtprHcEibh7RAGrUAaQrghopTS/iDdNAyVMhShTw1rbpohICbVoTyFvPUOrUS1G4ZwoBuGuCqQXPSAFutAuGYtgI0rGDjLSeznBA60gFqBZs7tEMgRhHwIbgQF9xaOc/pp1uTkd41fLPHU3YHmLSE3aCEZISkOSwePAtITUAlB2CwFwD6GrSAPJAjD1WbL2D2FwJ0YD4sx9kfcIlPsesjM0OGDczKIVa8aJMpO2Q3aeCOy5wTWJkFbROGi56ObA07uUFMKoRj@jKDTGAMNZxTHPOJ0yxl4xE36ro4xMPQ0Tdcl2FckAu8LPEtb9r1jJdTHJwWeA2AERrALwe6aUUIUOfUfeKq8Ex6kN98Ge2B64ypB4@RL1mOM1kzBgAXPENA950zY4H6gknqk4kFQxH4G3wkBGTOdBJWSLKJ58oRgkSYrjcyASBlBSzcdI0e0T4oOqTOA7NfRrHGtOatPEK5Exuj8mziAP/2MI09tawaDB5Gj@WbSt84VdCHj2PL4xfiEI5sMD4FILo6CBqIOWERQbqlyTRmHoU16znj5aJxpnUQFX1k4mhjnelzqL0B8Ctjpo9BHGIoc9gwQo6hxfAaxJoAgQ@LdcD6jp30IyhnLkgGUOioJCR9IE18c2yA6OhAEqzxAiGNLJMw686hKRO1CjLJihyTS4SShcuE4h6FmAfvLDCG9qc9pBrmbdrUgmDs8VBwcg29z/0E32XHxzr8XBgkJ4F4LKMDIz5F1GJSHIywBlA/EGd6BBEHfsP2QCbzZGai8Aotf@gMoLGdmVB2EJcg6QJ2j4iAJIi8ZnJPFojk2IDGJxYzWW8yYeAPQgg0z3u5CozrzhcmewWB1gjkst7UdedsNoGaMMcQy@85gwG03lfGZAQg2LjPevMedE@oZGw9Qt8hjtSbLBdz8bZpQBwbJb29x19jQwPIDlLAAEV7bPKLAkwmVAQihW5zCcHWgVJYhN5kTmQBMFGKgePI6N93DI8ai@OeRF0fM/OMIXUN6GeDBTMao8QDrdQmSa0PnCfoXggfMxRWFgazClrBR4YNXacHrRI6PVQf1ukuG4CGEpMLUHjTez1j4gftxCF2ZtoxIerwHgpR5CsFwGRvJGzeZtuXWg1EjVpOTEBAoRJRnwSynY68NlCDQGSwjYUczzmLNb@SPcQ4vZS7@ALjLGHwQlyDw4S6BEqUxCSmPrIS5I5mb4S80EduQ0IM9DZ3erX44BfP3h0zaRDljdiowHYEWYm8EI/1MCT4WVcByRMLYTWXPDDqkscNoHVvvAKyEyFp9eO@sqLLwBRvAjp2bGcFVCBmBBejLIdQXVBjfIpcQ7eixkjdxVuqI2TYC80cBzIYQycTx4WewZnOnNQzqrJY6wq0mlQ0VqRBq18eWmHISOKA7@MoCAkmFuhy1MWwp4K4qgOnACbGtQ7geQ7PMYYw9XqCFeB3RqyfNyYYS23bQIlXd@ccCBQPhmfIaM5M1wU2eIqDBB@DwsFEpnYKYwLoX8hZkRzU7y9nLmOL3pt2zdll1aaHnvIXnnCqu2yAWo0LQgd0olRy4CXTdfKnlLEgUXEmvkJJ@V2EiBRJhipPDUBRgkHiHjCap3O7lxKXupiYZeLUH1TENDgwIZfR2Mf6xL@M3Rfgh41mfAL9mt7qbAjDtyTBXUI/wgQDFBkDdBfkDOiEILpXq/2uzl4D9wAVfbZHqVHIpKcqF6K8DLsf5RUQAnGJl1fmWXhujxxSbFTDEmB0KjkNEksEfEdKUEIRPBQlGFvRg6Q9HkZyDfec2jSJwVJcFEmz80jYhwEgRciYIHyYPdPvBOLKrVuh4LLRaEBjA2kK2GY/HVcTwtkeGTg1RJZJGgkykX3nqY99I5WG8mLkC44NiE3QUhtNdu6PXOhx9H4hQCQgq2BjSw4JG9TzI/Nk2r9c0TZ6YiQRex0ITWbPF@sCDP68NzSuo2pyiaqgSiSRqth4MT2BvtJ4yRcrVAyiuYaH4m8jQCVWwynEIGirK0nEkwZ@iwa9N@9ZgUjAXdDZOTfqAvonwexAxIiygUwQdtorPZUDwe7A4bDHu0f3G0Ff5IFK17RrSx6W09Mt8t7E6GKY9sHBnSe7T77WWQHDMru1yx6KWaiUcKidzqShPVUKslbbjMNYAL7buR42JlyOIwpBMJOcWUxUmvdgcJmF5Dx88pXLJAFJCMlBOYAbf5dEGh4HhC6hq3ujS4MwG2YykGWUJIzLpAMWwowciDqG6yE@j6evXmHlXUZqEvgjZtZU5wBCT@XADtPJGHhJAAuDugM@IlJakEJNG2dpF654zBCfj1BqvowMidKxJvPR4b39Jw0CG0xWSBRF8XyQpXS3L0Obt6Z9Q1gVB9gfuHosIy8QR3macF1J4F5vicCLumVr4AMA1HVkh0nWOCyaNwLc9y6XjXylXtQC6J0gXJYr4/JQ730RjeGBQ1wPVd5VoygFLAaryGvliBWFLg9bvWLRKBeq8WGrt8izHwdKM60wDoRyowtBJ56EPvJCigzE6gD9pw@uIO6REAmqgBRi5llMprw8S0DtRTJZ0lP2QENzLEP@lDieyMS0oiTDyVa555HyGYu/PzP9VC7Nn2oa4kLuu7sH2t0wcjAPSDMZpDSgLo4jkzvAxZGeB23Edixn6LAtSMOlwzBDEJvWFnN36NhXakhHTyxqAtdXgP/ixI0@gbHGfEWKI6WKq6t8pUa3vTPg0mopj0QiChEoheLLX@inOpBrUe6nB5/vwyCiFnO5yJ2jC0gQS0PkQlcv5kseTIKM5ACflQWM1lqu9PYwQIotdmChA0YXJdxdBK/0JI4pKyvjr0TpY@cKxb9w5peaFvjwpgWOGMkOHj1@cPBo/@HuZ8e@ViwuvRdy1RIQDvLrgiwkjzjdsLdu8a6JxUJwCegbLnYv4AJTUFDCKfip5wLjljGKzBFY02r4KlXqY2dkJ7305cKcYaj0hd3jTeghdj4eNUgIinbfQmXE5Ut9OJ5j@xn5/sSrKQr08tG0K4PSqnzRcyx9qFA6GBgsS1FRdTk4xHkNb1UKQMabGzwFn9wC0WFOM4i6NXZAeaEFQ2QNLMXB06yVZQ5HoAvjqqLhpuWoBVNplD5oCKArK1HZiAHTG9A2eIb1JPKm/YGqVXi7VnNaQRHDaEvdH@JuDAxQnVIwWgEp0pde2fGt41tsDlwaIV0GkmDyFk1yeAzHAouBIEmzpqjnh8QhboHzpcgriEYvpzibC1xKKeYKZbVUVEAtAzUNZFYJ59ykse73RpLvSABPcgY0bxBrhQOvp9sDeStwhMiC3PchFDXfen58bLdBQD@@RbjhYl5r3m6p7XSdXU2yFcRP16H1LhUP227oAW2XnNA06cnW8LO@fpWd9XXqXX2m@ONJMOZIE/ZwFwSpVw7w674R73uYQIkHKltLcRWM/EZZMSFkYVIBb0gpBToUjLTQ9BTESwKhF8VDaDnAt2IJ2GI2g5eDL47H@Agq3djuTSfp0cw/yjU4W@pNgIg02dxDLu3h/KAPo2PU8pFLQ@Uik2ZnRhLn0XWPz1ZComDhNEwPuloEgWbloxlpO1oShkZAqUg9B84B7QqnTUeLWUZU@qGlQYaEE04@gARh0@rBEPgMJOYF2eUF4TmRz3KRTmznzEZoXYNVpK7p88l@Z@riAqLZj5cNouc1HgegUeFifJ1WGrtGj8@y8sRUClACdTY2xg5OJYB0RazAoCLofJUSdUEPZ6yhW@UkXIYB@BK7vQdcrGfw@SJpjEoUNKl9lvRdZVf6XNGlV9Car5GtsPC78WV2qvSjkADLa8Y0SxLMgJJ04owp0qc034KBd0JxV5jM/RGUGFqYqDeciWFf1vm4RphK12ltN5kEhm/aqfPkxsZGspZsJrPg2gHXNrp20JUB1w65JHJhPBldlCJLLgxtUQr0aycvWiHkWbqNbWCGksMrc5LSW7Vavp3VW2rw1PCZhqoAykNsCR8AJ5luNNCZTovNM1yzAfk9VvY9bDtPe645CUjwMQgE/D2gQZ6IAOo9SvOuUUfd9HqKjBsuKI0GipgpN3ncyh23j8@P@5nji2QWU6fregP0Q2BefmosD11nOgHBrVWoScDb0q18rV3vNpK55FYqVZEsyEhPpz@spDM6p3UqaUCbSh0fJ4GkAXVavZFL8GZZLZ2OCAV4DEzQMiwrlZTPK5B/N91OZ5KQNp3MAltuJJNAlx4SwaNC44wAb0T3zBmQEjomDHHxNQVikLQ4hd31c2MymrvxCNGsG0jZOIO@2ACA@ySQi8e55CuePi7QLWn6odzL44Fwi5N3KC9N5py7CxzTY2Vp@0o47p5Kg7Hj68onMihNcmy4TG4kFUmCkZBCOCQq9kPTwy6s24Yz9eIzjSsnQDF38D0aTYFZhnt7stCqzIlg9EYOS27eBugsWu/BoQSXriS@ABYC6Pdk@CETRakEF0tAuqBdGibwRdrfQrMyKiHBWU84N18sTV7KUW51SsNymJE5tB3XkIAkkEKgLSm0oUlosmBXzAHNfF1ZlwhCaUhDxds0gCPesxydaMvZdWw9aDKOpQf9HJI8MfqCBfxjAOxR5nXhGn1lS6BVWscdwQgBpUFOrEW1NQ4CFMeb9GV/BkmFFA648UCu3YHQecb6mqaVesVBLQzDVgHEHkEloVZqg4obBkkqBKaDSt7n00Khjv7o8O4@nzuhwRaHV5xH64yd/hTkykBvemLYwyzbh/Zk2s7YBDKE6V@dWE8cx@daPrysm5nhSrM5nlo6zflcnpa5Nl3P6ToWTQVdl3QRf@p6uqXzSagwdPeThyDrPzt62pBrsUiKfjq@Nm@ch1ydLafnQXzNkdZbw@UhjzdMcbMo4rgVbplDNhMElDBgGmyYgzoK/cvoH3YpXEMJ/CvoP8bNciArB7MI9Bp5BhGrFBE30OEuosDzXM1doP9aHSyKp1I8LjgusD1XNfI/9QeDJe88eZ9IyJqshXeBvPlGuiUdMY5SkUfCXXVLceKAShQn2lx3OV7AvKK9BiPDClcQn4BggqtkMLZbKD6BboKSON//ZoAgPcHFEOLQuMTGeiBrelemLaBPTSQeW0hsUD@BMUxByUXYVFgwxV2nnmI7wdKkx7mnA6o9zZ5sN/liNqpOLtfaFD75vtkBENvNerhZaV00zCmZjKIRVMINUlAxaf3@SlGj3RgezakLlKQueApoDTMtJx3Pyvvt10nFIzIMmHh8PPswp30G6gfuNNu8pQyNOma4jl71MCQZiKrdOZNAsMNYfH66NwJ2wjKzZVJC/UztgWP1Jb4YBu2CcTUKKyjYixDtgAs2OhqmG25@o92HPCmy0di@uStwL1Vp82qE2E67CBD0knP2@iR7@pq1YGQ7lb2JZfptdiH7TmeEJPGnrn15Tx4XNV1Xn3tCsJWlwXaffPRJK9fmEISxjgtcFV6Ls3BrJ8jHIA/hXltw4YYc3/RpwKcNByaWV5UBqRmthQD6AINnUGdRRkGJEPXXxutFWQYGKKQpAzH35uMsM9IX8sDSfd@weZvjq4zryc2Xg4JsGpT9TrC2UGM5WoABAdTEMECxzp4e3d1/8kSGluulkvu4UFOD7qj3RiCHrCt0SMl44Wvsw36SfYhp0qidC9DVQMnoBOmhUdeh0YOaAbkjixgabgo807jG0gNvWtaihFwQCwiE26p6PtEoApYy0lAmAlZbif8zm2tUAZ41aPEZoiSQO3WrBrQ10/LUNl/KHownJJ5ClCTXSWFYaGymiKltqmlqPa45xhViUKRINoQStFpMegVMDyKLrN2u86V@iIt6ljtE6ooiVQXtAG6oYdU3wBskF4IQJG@8Yc9bOanazmyuAkV7yILNu7z8MbgIYRm0Z6zMdjNF/f1KR@Y48CU/zsifkdZ8aYd6jW1yh8inlil6uC@KmA5to1reDrW82Qo6GbISmnHBgoQsIRFsrQ7aLIUT5wfVBpORRyrNziOia0hy9vo10ZBtaoxoCC6V8cq4CJVMYEwPHCjNg2BbdVwIoN4a7BfBPnssiKE2tbwgiyFcUldOLwmh0qkYT8eFQNM@cWhZJ3J1crJaRMEvSj0@sa6mHJjeiG5LUSMceFxtHXbeuDug24oItLoRrJuTB82bByIvyIq68oQeNIW@IuflvSJL2XaNwdQe0iIjupn08oaYUrVCkQfdrrkuKhABt3@FzxXRgElhe9bkgqyG@7RxxgXGI2BcXElZFP3yNiO2RHcYHXxIFTz/y9f7QP@rtTOCgQInGCNHB4ZurClpsLaygqT4QrfVFcvnwaeWqRNhyHUTyJ7uQpF0K3KsBk1r7ZIEw/8YVw6CGoe2iTcQDq9pZhxzvvAXPldnsmrtzAaW2VsX99K2K54VrfKA/tYnInAhyDQoEbEuXgnGjK@0xDRpZGM3IxXujWLUmHm9j6b@lN9BPr2xEs0J/q7rm0HMXFHvqgZoiHrXNK6pclc/mfYdaXIyjOTU0oq4i9LTUq8E4kCw6ttB5@ri8wK65hDG2fC5LtpiaFPO6HFTq/DsqTeRuqRs9/kbdYTxNTm4Fr@vi2IGB5wix3qqmRbd3rElBtChoQSbHhTcUirFiGZeIrOld@cog4zev5VFGwiA4zR6mUwuv2YFeTJZnx4VRkpfra5OPZN7nB6rpgIUvm1V4pNlVOBgI@sNtQrDlTnWLUnrx5xrmfmq/QdXokZLl5TGOMWFm9OVNbegPg5IvamluwvXNU18gUe4WrBu4jkYNh6bPQfEgQlTy7KqhUNHbMAglhnugFtkhLuG6Rbb5WCuImMf1EIcxKXItZoFOD0fd4auaVPvwND4jkzc9xprJLKzjlI95wx/a8WHEaim/L56RHu1Eqt3YE6S1bN0GMfXDgdLc4A4x3hDQz0zPYNuqwl7shJRv2et9F/uAuHsXny27qZm7ZmW47GndL@OQEMXqMDvqxt0nJambks05x13X8ODwq0MiwrVraFjlSpDRYfb2lqfugPk@8HzXTlcxKFU9QYOFYo/jq0Gz7V8/URxT26qIDrs5eI21pjzmiF2FZsKlljWlw4UA1yfW12ye7kKpZQVPqO3JmNcWTnT5@Hz5xg61pE2HDomcxKnQbrDBNUKOHyXi9g/T26F63PrvxtTugK2fFMhYpV7YhkwWNH9SpUyLae@Zwo1l3t3FjWwpsbUWKloHHa/MPDo8TVKxrsjlQuKsRlMyOMaAJ5AiWK9CjTDd8Iax2l8u5aZ6JbZM24WZZaZ2gSk7wmqzo/B8RgdV1MM7elkqVaXtDP7yfUkG03CLu30l7DDkPflQ5UbJKUl@dwz6HetxsQ1PNwH1ijkcrlAgIktrCy9XKdJ5aO0X5j8vpQx@SxyXsTFxTQ35lydB5ElvtNwLQvS1in2FLlaVWzTNvw53t@Rm3Ydx3qfmgKm2jdRFAPJknbUXldjV8Sd4KwIW0xdeDjh0R2sm7Tgo02gWwJ9UGm@rtLjKz/vVJsSrm2Ocd1p@fX66ZvYOtJNueCZbZwT4ntsrfWyZDAbosoVuXxtr@MSqtM1LJ0/ZqXCdfCqcv5aeMtMI1iTxTVcvnK7WHFPXGJKkzkQy@yDljIyxga9XiPl6300LxA81kaaOfhbFzwzjJ4y2zd66yJMTOALNt6XlopjwpLv2KBf@bidD/UUCzeMBr7rOHC4uLeSyAdjfWhwuxbXccrFhAVumuFq3cK5euqixjfK9CDZwpDB@iYBnerEmHvhcyXAh/Me1Ot0fPN026XO38M50Hfo7et2ql4dYu2RM7JHxohvD4/e1nUOaI8@t0NyHeqA9XCEO9Ymk6Wd7HF6Wo5lvQs9kTVyRuk4g5U47eMZVzyg9V5w53oXAoLHjZN3us95BzrW9pqRMYVxyXN8Z2JI9LYuqoUTPfy@joeGa9E/7wzStXo@UCR8/rzwb9Qth7rjTyb06EysqUc3SirR0eSb5KYB34FCex8ddyi/csZdOfCUg@0ptAS@msV0Tb83wrPhvGUbQ6fbG5k3Id01dN82T5Rwyoe/vpPuipQxmXQXvWXLBPK6cxnbSyMe/hQfB@sqPZg94sNa5LhGXlk1Q0enr6WJftLz@GwoulgNJ4RjvZGf0a7RKffay6npL4DGtixF07t8WQId63APNkmslazoKMSCDQebJ9a2UhLSUSCXjBwIPOq6bJe3s8W6WD7Pb@sQipeSMIptP3kfcgdbfGh20IzN24L/Uvta2pu0cpCzR9Ohd5Vh8un6PohoeFs/bUFblmNT1jBm6XbwWEdmzVLwLCM8OyBzTY1r11SK1y6qUDzVknTHhEcHHlB107VzaJY58fidSYO1S3HBliXQxS@vF3LazFcr00HF9I0BXwJB100i4thxccMxyCBSD1fScQYdmTkXvDjjsp0hMHXJYovIYdx1YsvK3UCrqz8aM6XPHhlDHbdUPzB93JO5olVQk121i@hG2F@d6p751SmUbF1jQ8MMfBnSjZ/gx7cV8B7qQ7N3f6kiIiQDAgcbOvljqfmj19W6OBuZHu5oihzXTExhk@ONGFtdB/SGFTEvz9tHNikWHYifdlwZe9XcujOZ46GwObmum1Y3fZplDZ7rVMd1e72uReJsOp5MveCxGgfaMxWfhR6fkL93ZgJw6SWwVjbSLX/1THVsyhWksGBQXDjXSeOfm5YzZJ9XcgyENhDCUDhf0XDuwPD8GDfkuPaKlkh5v@OyJ050SC4v2EuoWyPPJNM2/etnc3wfN@eETywMHznwIILyAO/y7feFIB2tpsiDm2X9xQnkG8Z3aHlPnanbM9AZmRWJqwVBrsZeuMkYD244aBblLK6l9RwLuhc4rJVdpufYU19yp/a1o0Lp2lGhxmaVUqwZsNRX9x8@S8dbA23KvkkKNUD5m3rWfOFau2HgUiMzbRDE1vPR5dihLnGXm0N6QjuCb0izizabesSu7zqr9J3HcxhA3llhAuY/Hd81erhseGPej5yHju3AaDQBRjl@YvCj/UsbPVYnxGQP8PA60Kd/YzZPCeyaQYhLG/rE6EL9WgvXu4xFHPBd3dfXDEU0N0j6X@S6sa2YVtdwv6BJv5h7nUq7jNB9Y0a6xfoGw/ug5Pd6XCTG@bilPrK0YuNNHMfmd@K2OXioD6/nKjAU0O3dF8pl3G@/NC@wUj9bLurhKd8lYvS57Yl1ZXWNrmPx@zV7kmyT7wnQXdPwlAdoyoD8SgUmgfTlXctDytfykIVqBJLsqe7RIv1qVWMBUp29xxagke72HFwJCxzX7M6J2R@4gU1HW/j5xoEuEH4GHEvvTQNDizehZY27Y7qtVRhitfnE6OLhny4Z7fD12dXK5DNDgcWC2I6u6Jx/yK6wU5dY6jFoI@mbh60lPWqZquaEbsSp1y6X02YdyTaN3isdZ80cotdibnopHMqsPCLnmrnqWDeiWWRFpwPtK3vS8tY1EGgsQ/JHLuj8in/d9HZoTWXFesh0bOAi8/IqzFrR1fFGVFhn9Xp6xFxdQwpM@gEvicz7cflQ2l0reSJ4@D@887ECg3CnVAgtjADrunkFH5CfunbweJcW@Njx/IE5OwS88RTAOnaCxSpCEnjwnoGurXWFgNqzpxaffRjG9l2N@6SOSWTBVpIsYte@IRn2qUT23mZXS@Tws13KLlo@9Y2@FJg7wJUG6UF4zCuKFjxXLKDGeSNu9lQVTthZqRBs/1xF3LOQM4C85fjSxKOnMvEeHzw4PJInnrpyfNod4emIK3Lckv0ErZKLTUl9obux9U6@Ha1ver5y56kq7T04kDHCGnrzFQ0JHrgyt/RYO@8ZmBXVFX2tFoShhr9aQLx/9PBBZnESk6X2Rq4zNtLx4L2nT7N40uTjpyuD46nvQe8YOLO1yQ/2VTW9ovk@s2l1cB33XJHTOkhHBmij0Bjvc/MrNwpXPWdi9I/mE@MTGDyRg3vvmH1pbSEf6afmEHshq64lFHVUVpVLhXRsZzYo24YbPdfV54k5QW7Zo4fCH2u3o6DkkFfc/Grp4boV/8tSDMsFOxHeL5Gau9pafVOCnjEcoUvRvb8vYqqqrqPzU30A9cqKaytrOcKq9WHLOX2HpWQjUF6kyEvyoVVJ5o37yMvSGFi3gjecng88wdlduw3mOgCRd2llhz8z7LluS7SWdZ14UYPUuKnt2iifG@@wIBXt8DlFQ88r1/iiLfUs1SNn@oaMj9xYkr29Owc3JXgS0PL6WB89esYe6x7aGrk@Yhxj4x0wXkhGX0g4b4WG7tYup/ZdAKVdC284Wd2fa@yp7vYdez67eRGOjpri0E42hCNY@EaRDMucmavGqh6f13q8epvRTXnzQxzOfEkOjtugCQC9/da/UNVcjiwM4VPN8dcbaibs4CyFLn2OZuviQUcHEWvoodwig0d6pTb6wJjhdhQ@G7xKqV85vpWuGfvK6fXDyXVhlWvCCtfkdyUMPVlezqnXACxeE8aKchT8wLHORo68p7uGt2L/8UqEritI9ZqCVGPc@VUlh5OgtLAYuNeL@Hh0IXisbK1Hhu8WJiOnaxZWlmF3gLYk2UO0iX41PNhOobu0vWXoBEc@@Pvq/M6mxsqMHuqvVgcQpzlZGQRM0BhN6UjE1eDlBdIuyLyGPTS5GUV2x/H36W0lko8d3LG@Msu75uTudLIeUWCJaMX/MhdfivgpqMrOmcfu4Im4hXS@QuXHbXGr/deJsiyaD0QjovePdsNGdfhU0WI5LrD47PGSN54Z9Q@fxvxcYzZbp@tKs3Wq48qQRa6PjgpL2W43n5@uINb6Y0YgZQAbjp5rxR/O4z5@epUToNY28sdWGPKxbi8mSpcqrO/4dMBwZeDj@Yx2T66s6RHfvLYqzF3VwJb0eRiHTRPy9pROB@3mdzorFWF@RvLJ1I6b0faygSEUfqaYn@T05NDWeSplZzLp9PLXOuLHUtHYbGoTjS1u0hFUiPv6NdsIjn1CgBgeJA0OuqJNNlBDDTypKhAIv7EJ2TQaarHKdvDzGDUQMtOUI3qR5aswrxbbPA/OcNZq6gXbaDCxJrLgFG1kyJYbYwW4aEYSysSkE5Vt@hCyGZ4AZfRdAfaakeIKkrJazMGbrMTPwteDM7KA0ub544PH@0@Pdo@ePW3l2hfBGdqwELYNuYUn9T/M90Uoe0A2GBC5aWY6u21BdvTNA1R4vbBcDEp2qWiNpaItCiXuYJrNc9tWFDpGrEgXgJ8k8twoFKRb9OKwwxJT/QQnyGv8RC8dTIYq4qBFyhPqrMZyqzKe6MDcN@0g/PK3XCgUv/VTw6/9YMaBNV1ovUPH6Qc5ega7@QpzvLd78ODZk30WIrhoNGdm3x81qkVubJmbNoB6Gpi0r6rBkkGSJNRVo5G8lwTCJOUkq9HBbzJ0DO0cooXUwSPjQeotltok@EDBZFQpyn/5unKRlHGLcBriJkOkkpAtNHlqKBsbG@wIGgm7@@Tgk/0nDPHfv0veSCIEwY7w1Omf/bjPPxUQGn8Jv3Pkjoklk5ENIX7yPDyOvTgxjjSnrjtZ/7UjMs1P57KjbwJEHzURBPpkBLTbM7LbdsmmV5rM7PCvMwUm18KMqAmF5sVxNhrNp7keOzU9E0@FIw4DtGa23NhxAwtZ8JPZLn7KCT8YpdN3KwD1qe1zi0GBfZEEtDQ5YjlZtknI8q9ciLGIye0NaOxdAwZp5tmg4ht@jX0BLRFnfGvcaoAkNZNXkoSga@SSkMPHIl4xf@Ypx67y9tf@mTKsM3D74P524J7l7sDbrwRvA3D/Knc/V7ChXTWXtsAljhCaOAxKwBGJ6I@0j33ByuaWGhaEQ6tuIV9l5hiq6ZSojtF5DvwuATtewEm1PoFKg@YGNRZYaOD5GW47hTYWa4qCTQoFR5n2xxszvlntkq3FUrFUUBVAUjoNAZJx9CGewuUA0@kadBPh1Jw0XoBUsr29zUTUHo1Gqc5rVtm0n@fFFxGimxBXOBshci0GaSDJIgWENYNkMPhk1DQmRe6VVJPIuPoOjEoUjqMXvtsBIUSWAmJxGhlobXuGHzvz3XloM7SLnweLfThjMwAkqTAmkSstCoFtg0eOD80HOuni0zjctgFu1uQjIBrj8/in/shUJ7ZH@WrPWhzJDb/QEfQ1GXkAB5XPXR5M43UrfoogniKImriq@baes2P/2G4rvG0yaKY/WNGYbXD/sjJc02Z5uXevGmpMXTaziMRit5/aDqrJ96AwLKUpWl5RS@lFkQqFlUUKShRkA8VBMzGvITtgU8Ayeob5hTPxdvf2Dz4@fPz0ijFCipm8HA34fnM7cyzJ2VY7ciTjxVqukjv3lKcP79wLK2KBdCnGjYHxByVRryvJYvYLQS5OU1wu2ioML5duPcaf8vPWl/HNa9ehRomu4KHm3iNf2tEs3aNzSZcz1yqrqFUsXofSAp4SA73HD5VeQTWVPr9otbebx3YiebUlrOgIzxPyFnYCcB17W5sKNvarhcOCRR/hPMIvdHnxvphf3RfFzTzaxMIz7b5zsrAGFnjEAmLlDbMBFinIShh1be875DL6wmadxj8Syq1nxW0DxRAu5a6jeAzUUfi9UeQiC4ubgbHJEehZltkVQptM3OhkaBsvsjfJ7Sml0kLw3QaecSr4AumsNpNp@1IqjdyOYGXZdfYrQ3hpATo0SnePp6DfPXYm3I43LVPfNULXEwfYL2jfpN8a7OPpGOIN6PHEoCUD4NwSJAZKJiNUuSwFXCIwXznLoIFQyK@FRiyDgsvjfjE1S8sjY9Y3h8DbU@kscLQPVbXNIhOXWGgyaWknRaqzRS1c2xU/wqPCcbK/l53T2QIBvaXLoD8bs1TyLJmutSF/9E@efXqaTIur2hLZWw0MkPYvG16N0C@r13MS3Q96Z2jVdBW3qFavcgnwuwyYWwYLPyJUrcojT6CPwjVQcn/quw/ACWJEajDWJyw1tblVNZnRa@o4ZWfJ3JTU5IYZbZbJkEIFDwqQGaUckIuP3yndnrOU0oBGgL6e3cfHK3PCWqost8FNmaTZJn7caw8kLjQnmBZAB4YkNQLbwCYEagZgxDuJzBs4pMFwiAsPsk23Ipi@dUQzqw7ShErNmrdY7GNty5KjWK3Wggpd5opVBq3vKjuUFQB7hc@Fcj1QNzC4AjQD9VcWEgtGfpXjJSjfBEfkfmCpBdBJxIyphgZcGMBamDrtjVz8pfZt6CsgH9Rqz47udSppRWSRxZeha/Zx5p/bA49UvOALLtBNlaWoyTrX6D7CZGhbr8NNyqCJt3vUYcRLLDURJ8Pl7yov2qaqXtvqg4RBLUDMAg4Awcm4TggOjUiGczYrwlYz@5/9DL/cLKY2VfWk455mksVcHW5qvciK7MPNY0nabOUatzd10KL8l7Nj0MmVrcLdU2M06B4MlWNRZHlWUJSt8/Pkva3H5nOt9HJ2kVcrL08maqklv5y1xUoje9Jmjx9/9qbzJi3OTucvxeOURl8W3jt8LaoFVPQTtSo73ynlEydV/EAn0/XiCZuB3spO2Cu4TgYM/8n9qh9z6@juDl7Rh42SIkscH@MXmcWyqCitZBv@Sd1/ARdX/FtNuSnvtN@8Sbd03Z/NmWmaE6/fh58zAglSSz9lkO8t4PQUX2HH9CQFiq7xbLCYR9CLcGtqeExSvt1BHzLTONs1hsPpvj43p/f8h59/Gl7P8Hr1ZMWERDuTSUlS67J3raMXE0zLaX/2k42L7PnjzvaffWOsGBv4OMTHty8eovupWvxwY@PDO3cKhaymadz9@PPHX9vd3S3czRYft4o7BSm3sf2nf7KxoWnbmrLR9jy1nWydnHwmarmCKP/Zj5Kdx4@/6nnN/P/59TdNFW9luJ2yMvAJuPJMBSfeK/BTUcZ61yvxKgGtXE3M6a@TCP3PN5ja3Cn/1@8evkz4iaamfOrC00@8TJQqCe4EB7zlw7fTRDOxjdFKF4m50mg0wFn@r/8O0jc/BjgYMt@GW7MYwirNE02pQUleJ5olcKiaBvn@31//egxDziYaJMaF123WgksslDVxpw3XFl3bAlrSk3KKEsaz/ZFvOEyt3FJv4YsJL/CwDbQ8bvjHCfzcLTu8zdiTViaTacsdCS75Oc4RKaqqHavqLeAG0odbjYa0xbipwHy@eAutGqdpRmvowIBp3GKf/mNciVWe9Z8b3BMhUdq4/eJuswmFyjfzW80MXUFPok5VroiOc1tkWfYiCSpIq/3iAe85rCnmKpqYzWZ5d5ohqaTZoiXhxe@JROSDXZZd9ltKAlEC38T7x0vs4/Xn/9uff@/Pv0t/36Pff0RTg3bfHChbEOkUukQTrtu1Wq/ZFJuueH6M701oR7lapVZROhfHqS3gQO0nTM199DpZzCefMmT/KiQ/TlNquCjbZpA9vjcTC@8m92nG/YIAHpk8WFAKcixRjdwR1a7Eg6E12JQptU6bbQkFoobUUkvFtsRThVg2q6x1G6pJ1MpVsd3UitohVJ0q8oobbXrMSYBmWArpGODbXJStGYUs3ppxr0QzTNZcxHnfeCG6TSHRailtgwaE0I/d3qhtVGqlmqZ0Is@rF6tf9TIM47GXOE1EF6dOYkHQRNQ0L/uFVRG9sLAFs/eJB5IRe5@r8y6cmu3AtQF/9A9X9Ir3DfIJvCnK1WuD1dQtLa8UPyzta@z9LgHGCdbrdruvel0UA/Su3tNVX5/qM32u@91pd9YFGYpN4QcxZSmRL6qbiVvXFklIvGltsCecC7VZJryOMzdez2S5EzjJ4eBPkpxZQkj8I1xNVVPZFoxPObiBUEZO0JnxT1UFljiHq/1mq/VmCzpoM7NN3LHdlAIs4SF3brcz0sVFC9z1evC/3Yycdbq4CwrXvshktp83QfR43mxlAOTzAKQsMQIqd5rtbQqJMgtyC4K32yC8SJnt1nbD2aMfJIFLShacZMm53QbA20vI3r6dkcF1GwA0N6E/pjOZTUnawLGxFYwVELndzISlQhxSIC2cn/@cP1D0oMtebF80L1rbFxfb2/C/TfeL4Am@F9tX/umxuNbEWYS3kbUct5TmsXIcMIo2vMtKE31k5RgcTXhCvFZeq7Rb6IBLbv@3@S9nF/fIB1Fuy4C1kNhiWwk0fJdPbAmJF2@//F/wd/z2y99HeZHBn1ETEufYrZUt1DarXOmEG7Mf2uwhv2xw4y98RR/0eNhET5vfbFyQUpQXMqvxOf@UWimlZRyAO86gg2fpZfYCoqLgBuMSE7VKSexk1LnGEttiqUwj0y9euZLJ5D95oVXLST49g0fAX3ie9zCG2wI7iFzXcqqkvm5yK@f8uxO/uOr6J7@47hISr6vMqAFVeh7j9BAS0HwSkgSjVHN7jFuEcX1EQlX0tPGZ9GxXwrkT3afVrx6fF2gc7Deq1SZf2tl8TF1l6@4W3FX439@AUggJqfsS/x68wj921MO/Jy/xjx29wr8nPv6xh138O3qJf7td/Dsa49@dl/j30Me/Z0P8O/6FfF6ti5vnRIGMWlUvNmciUaKe2Gke/4LvzmuWYbfMfjv4eEu@UGXpxPEvGDP8hHeNew6SP/3ON76RbDSSUpI@iVFQHZep6ToQGVD3kvXbSSHRYJvqppqzcr2c2lW74DBZzmW5UW6k9kEL6agsZ7DcPDdnubGj9sFlwF8OXGZuwHJDlrNzNkSEUHD5nZyPrgE8hvA3AEAu/Jm4ta2r5noMMrJQJKOv6SF4cL3uHAstlmTiCwMUSVmVc3LJbOM3SFriixfHylZbq1aYjG1H7rReHCfbaK1aqxZYd25sHL/osIQHqmg9oRwfK5wmUFwi2cVFp7P/6G6no@CAcvzQOVz8Hx6O46/X/o8PnYeHztiB/8PDQ@gERjNzOwOs9vbtBrDe4LGTaNZ3jmvEwEMmnlC2d46beQndpQzwZQ39Mu95LSDCs7lxLCTPUqhFnKEiUf/0rH5aJ/dZ@AqOTn0RIYzGHcETrjMYrELF4gyu0zN00Bs6zz49jlzcoXx6Bl6fMlChon9Q1eKv/wD/5n9b/w@fsTRLtdrp1PnFdoquNP6l0@cX5xfBvZlOpYKX1Db8oQe8Y5LziyY6KdI5uFqpdDt9ccH94J5Kb3OATchmu0lpF/GAwSeiLClbfkv9wz4h6@A6TtYZcBxSk4s56kcJsc70xQ6Z4@NZLpeud0PD@7jeq7@mbQjpOn1cbbPbUtt/@iP6uMJOmiIVC/W6usX4i1bQ6vVC@Fau1OuV8GUzlapevZq5HbUEmkShkE7X6/CyE4LNwWsEtgJgw5ciQDU8vRcwz/ODQ/rsAHCOYgK/98E5RSpHHy3B718lxZp461Yq@K72zm761i2tmnv9OvKZTMBLXfLqdPqm2@mgf/71a7Ej0oaVahHec5XXr9VcNaMm046beoQfToOsUpLKPtSalGsVWLJWKKfZP8gFwIrb26VCs1kqgLtUwaVzKjsTN5OJ83BcL6c5b0xuKlCtqABB78YxwWPnFwmqY1YoplPAXdMg4F0k8I97q9Uq90@zQilVyVSDv8YG6NcgrvA/lLnymcJWees2SK/4N1t5IU@unxsN9aJxbtRwfvyi3gu@UYtn@41bt/JVoGElVz8WOp27u0e7nU5DFEUUeeCGnsTdBTR54CZbVL3FaruF5WvX6repHaiVIoMK53GkJIwQrAK1omhbRbWCpBDMAZrugPILKlFyg20IGj3xJlQ5fTfAExQTzBx/fbhYn3XZEC82xLlOZjKLLmYxHk73Xi@K5PArCI1eKS1ekY8RXULi8YPdvf2jrLYtsYR2b3cvqz19dieh4mtx8U7BeXx/sr979/AZJHj8YH/36f5HB5/sP3sM/h47W1whpw/ui2fcteL9jH0qfOG@0g1DN6aG0TmbTs9esi9Ms2NCDVpTKIQzdJlndAD3ib4oRx1@PdPTv/hCdyd0sbc/@NbbH/x3b3/4nbc//NbbH37vp19@71vw@zH8vsOf3/m31SLef/rlv/jdt7/zQ/D8j/D7I/j95Kdf/ubX@Y/e/xh@/znm98fBLxaP/wSA9Ss//fK7P/rpl7/6ffj9q@D3/au/X/vJ6t/3vrn@h@m@@7vXx/nOv4Pf73FYYdzv/A73w@eV@L/D4/3q99/@xr/n/38a/KHzh29/44/xFrz88@//6X9@@43/oGmVP/03b7/53bff/Mbbb3777Tf/qfb2N/@Nmovffvft9/7gr/7w9/7qD/9H@v8x3X/vXf7ffv@f/8X/@hf/@1/8YfD7Cfz@Pbh@8hf/AfrG3/7BD/D/u3/wt3/0A/z/n//13/7Br//tr/xP5Pgt7vh//tW/5fe//rX/9De//e2/@snX/@bXf/I3v/UHf/V//Or/9Zv/6a//@9//63/2DfT8rZ/81R/9yl9@41t/@c1/@Zff@HLN/VvX3r98B/8v/xF83h3Pd4HzLuV6X58vfy58/j7UWOQC7QRa9y@//c1fggb@G4y9/daP8SgM/Nb8/1hTKc6P@dv/Bxza1TJjSA5c8Pv1t9/6DpLofwASwX9Er29HL0sh/OXbixcg62@vSPTLP/3yX/6I3hJGrUmLLjhgV7RKZguUmq1qNRi0g/UYSPJLy9AiAEFO30YOtRT2beRtb3/w9bc/@qdvf/Bbb3/wKzhgSoVqdjcrqTdMkULE4jvEw4ild4mHET/D/DM0QyZlPoM39lkQ@Nlnnwmd1wqeubr9Gnw/Iy9@MR6EZ7KCoDAM/fGQFnvN4u7AmQucm4FvlDNjrRcv2rhcCn6Ye4YEjq1QHirm2SwTIDZjfFkG/SHSbIucM7yTLwbPBLwt/hfOmcAyGIdf@I240EmOIF2QBXcKRcgmM4sWg0hAY1wk2uI@tMxL@RaqDEswm2VmoPmCA3LIQNCdDGs0GhlM2OD4wCtHrVlhhEom04ByY2qeJtupIIjZHYICKRuZJ6yz1ZjxhBmE1wzJkRHQ64moamKm0rgLGTZmdxnCQuAE9sWLRrPSmDUR3BtOj8wsc4dwQmCNzKz5Bt4bBBPSCYm7bwCVSiOTaVYwQywkr55sh1dSkQpHZc@wTFAH8MTd@ju3GftQVCsiXwDYQILx2HjPLGJjRIgO4ceZraA49B866bdFBN@grIJcGA/fIYF0h8uoGAHgSpIsywx@uH6@w25D8IyDylC28MhwCBlqEdQCIg@GM0AZIUP1m6EXyD/R2HrvC4FhYTY3N4VEU8yLhzKRTlGYe1Kjowu4mw81kBoTS1URvQ06xxHiAunrlP9mEtfFkowDZh9m@O/27S32IRSTngs/gUmZvFNwEhzKdiYjagC/6WSE56CLCNBOCdBrQZ41SNvJCNksY3IjgWHs8PAwQII8njeEDDRzLa/iO64GTafTBKSQ5ayczQZPmZ7kIQcOmUKDp7yJxKXvDTNNK9RBZaoz9GJx/UYFvRc937x5A7VC26NqB6CSsmCnlFaoUCB4cNMTljUPz/toharA1XGmlgqMpWiuFK40SwssxbbSAt9Uz5EIr1RSq1SSFA@oL6e2wo1zJZWaA86TJpqIaHhxrbFSTIeBe4ds7/Dhw/1HR5N2mwkGfT/Z6Excp2d4XgrDdh/d5QcqtGopnWi1EPRRTUMGI@zXcsSMD@4@OXhaY7zQQRWkCLE6LYsGxayqQmIy@XQ7EWwcEvHbYI74FO@1RdlSWjUPSRNNIdEzULPA9e46bRipCw@94R1nBpp@VhSzagnVuTTNDjPha86UoeVKbuYC@hQes5C3t4kCQvNcopUHdEJtlYRmM9hyx1Sh@XT/CBIcHTJVy8lC8zM2kzFD6UJoWg3LsIf@aBP3ronHOTFWps1WLot/Wj4Pd7VQyqrFcntjwzqXMM9jqrZz3IR4Aa/nEhbjA7iY8IHAPgAvuCAP3FnIgm2dB4f1YG8d2ohK8Q12olqEbpYWjqGiOThhsrgAUWjdy@s4QmLj88991myCUi0d3BMSwC1GLNxeJpl9eSRTNfenrkGhQ8b65icmfvRN7pvexNLn0HWAGomLi4sBQDq4x7SmRq88RR/vFz3y6YL7YqYLCbtWa7xRC2VBO6nV3uQ1TQAPYUvB/Wsb0ABoG8CWwv/qHmSSz1cU4FSqKMIjn88LODssCDVDYLTX402u0ZB4G8wXVNrqIeB3BPRZQ4uuIO7sw0XcfI7HxRAIYEPfZbkwrMzDgreSQG9ANNzcRl@trQedM3frVh5nLvKFXDRFQSVmF1A3m/lCHiku/P/X8kUrNNuTZj6nbisTcOrgLGwrOji74CxuK11wmuCsbismOKfNvJrbVqZNgQnb3FwkQ2sUDdE3ZmidlvuJTc@wBjKeEWqIlIEmbgfml5thwma/0Xd69Inpel828VPfeIiUJygUxLpjoyGzBpo0oGO3LJU@F4aNMzrqKhiNoYy2MVxbt4S@3HX6c9nz5xaetrEct5EEuTAZBiygGyCQ4MzXTj5fqLVYW544kx1BK5YzLTUHIwn@1EpWy24YO@VyrS/3LEN3d4q1YiXbx4M8wbLVTjFXG8qfPXxw3/cnTww63bNTqEICtCaFdl92KrVisd1qiWKmRdm08cu5nE9JGxvQuQ29L8Fz4Ni@J2mVNiTum26jkUzu5FVNUmv5XOVCWBAOaY4lbAqYNIMlyyLdzwNWULMdG7hOLatnzXOiQm0wGFxsnWcWL4J@LvE3oM@FpGe759FrXYrFq7FpVjIXgeCjD4Dc58F6XU3UihWx3qov3sslsd6@EG6Pjb6p46Ge49z51VQl4M4cagIyOmbCRc11HL/WNQaOaywi5tVSGJEjdDVCQbyIsjvOYY7nV7MrxSLNzq9CKRTFiyhViJZwcQF058SGfsFNgTZp72tLrRba@8CKWu3t0Ego1k3i@XNdbzahks8LZa1QLBS1fKlULGsw5FQLpWIFulmulCtqGgAoVCvV8gW0aCGh61KzkdfygqZJWl7Kq5Kax/8bHBr@v3t8Df41vEOqvCYcoaWNRzCWwfhrswd4Yt932JGD32wZsjtGb02MvZFOu4T3XMfz/h5x7uj2CQ@6a3LzllHQfR0/XOWNTX@0JsazyRiNdBjuPxqE/XEXEETWxCPcgZtrOc6qCGX27PGaUj6MDEoDMbhFaYj@5OCj@0ex59H@7t59ocTuHD66e@lRDCIV2YP9e0fRa5mHhkmLEYiv7T94cPk1eBQOnz0ZTB0Xf8K9w2eFxS3ywkOoQgGu5UiRNwEJbvhK0h4M86AdFcuhQxXw6MIt0FhvBc5iaeHMofNTfsLW9KKt9PywdU04Co/d6gy5XtdgPW6LBVVospMWCNhquSoIE2Y7Z6ycY33HsnT8CvdgAzxHOh4hNFDKtOgj8pj1meNa/TOzb2wID/G0YlXFLx4jEsJ9ADKe9sgoEUgYaHWzj9/HxhWkrjU12BS/Tb/GEx7ohU7XHI5gPDxzwghCV9cZ/N73gvRG/PKv9/B5HuR3JcS6Gl0ARUsU7@u@fjtRadW99qSZq9Vu3VIfu2I1L3pDY38GDZY9gw6ku/NsRfRl8R6TO4khLjVYJbXgTJp6E1SDFgjSMIruFDSjWckV//q3f/x3f/LrVa2hbh3n9nLbOw8fFGvAG0G0ZCQ9BhKmTLqGVq0UK9W8VslWqpVCUS0Vi1lVy4KaVq6CpJ5TK2qpUqyq2UqhChJBoQqhxWo5kE@VUCBVtmoA1u7hF3i3SV2RR6CX8BVD9iqlp1lCj96nTDQgjSigZujTcewtswGDGVNzLF9mAFFnPZa4d28vd@@eKN7BF9w9sZcTxT6@FCu5XPmOKBoUsldB6UZ0eJoK2jITff6Sy93ZE8UpB4BmwEVxhC/7JZzjEkUTX/Z2793DfAb4omF6iHbCQ/iLFb6UIZqNLyA2E4CXETSItsvzKRCi@/iCWWLIPR6yB2Gi@FGIDoY84dE4gPthSXd3RfGAv@zuYsgeFbvIEf0KvuzSJYouvEDTF8UhOIYudDpR7IITO4Ao9sDVm@vgh187RkvRtq@L4pyTBwkkijOKrfdORLET@mM2nwTYFJG6NXpRealv00sV/0RRC5HGaPnoJS@KheilAGW7f/8TfeT3jSG/5i5/9qCk9@/ndXM23b/X/eij7nDYdee7@x89waC9vfsgGcynbnfYDRJ2O3A5kGrvvqafjOeXLyj1QadT062VQV/pdAq6fSmoM@8YiCGkegmYBdcQMxp39iBo737ntr5qQZcAdrDvj@HZxevOGJ539C4PCi8Koues2xXr2PxRbMdVWOyJJ8BG7exY77lOHd9njQ3Gkqlkdt4q5dp1CmBjEL9z9QsMH6TwruNcTPp83po1cu3GrFHW@GagQUo8nmlFU8xujHfUarG2oe@oWiEzq6ExCGeQZElJ3WEp9dbWK5Z6lN7RQBQXj3d2JLGltnc0tVIrlZ9vTUUxXcP7Tr5cg4i5ZI4xvKVb5fZOuRhLUi5ndEWrlcvp@gXQw4fBvItzJJ1U6szQT9JpRBc1digClZXNqZxmfZCaZWcNjhebp@uzhlrnxlFZ7gqsPlrinvZ8x@UQhwButpOr4TJ4SlSrFRHyV5RUOo2qNOnKirDYT/npV49Ojo4@A07IhGYwk/CYfzi8Hrx@dH9PPjgM39CCtnwP1R/HlfeQXS2FcAPPodcRKALyfRg9QakK/fDInetY8j7tVAMdKgwI7aLKgTVL@ej@EpynI@eM54wWC@pkEs3uGQwNjJt9pjea4NL7LEVYMT19RuN2p9lsdBpjOtQPRQxTfYWR9e0FmAOP4x7ZUaDk53gMLQjoNHIX9W5jlpgBnE6DSeqLsdN/oWV69T7aFb/TuIOJ6x14dutGw3BdxxUTYn2wYzcYm9qePjAeGy5aCDk43AQpAs@mpQbMSG@y432MvYfqwoXUdJm9wOzRdJwCebybXvaKvSJpUl8Ni3xOhyVxk8RFfdBgqefp@kt4dTdZqi/fSe8U6v3UHdZJg0/uxeDFgGmsVKjTB39TCAk6EdEGy6ynG82vgODDAZ/UaoBIUMcnABNzArBmnwL09MS8qPcaFktJbMbSRJ5CfdhoYerXeNuWRLEtSa3XbaEpSZ8KTein9XlCb3jTLn2MguW6qpYr1Wfgp5YL9RFUrP58Vncbk6lr1C14DabV@JlQvQ7kBKoBmFevU29/6evpbanY4H51AvXaAlmjI3cas7qN5u2gSTTyDQjItAq5LKjQcCtnYZjXSlm1lM1nC1mpjL4wxmeLWfAEtQZEipSVEhkTs7lZTlazqqFmU7kXZv9FOnuSAlGFSMbSWd/Zt6djBj5QSdgq6RWeOktntC2LQS04TN@WqJkCp6hjwYDmIzYxsyME9cTQLUqRTkssv5WyNlMYZ/NoOtlvtWu1/dnkqxCUkl7ulDLlXOZVOl1PbaQbnvFSaNaFJnIVKvVkA9psMOPIvOm4BXUMLrWs1VqtLhaxnMvmc3kondl5PdwWm2I7m9soqVBFF4zEI8Y5RnwSDoWchd@kg@K2ZUDVqVWtLsg0I5avaFJVKW4Vc3xWjqcUJgFbQ0qy1LEYnn9OJZNlLZlMJ@u4HrAhBhPAwMuIjyWBqSZvqTsiyF9iTaxqGGHBEumIay7EDiSwCwFnH1ihKiTOhYvzi23QhRXaPwnyItsglyQ3bwuJGmMgBh4HFpeUDcbed1tmZrv5nD@PcWc9wBXIDi1IoLRdyjBR/2Kf4Gn@HZYExHR33NK0fLullWEgA@YYRgUtvI5LIAncuy83gcLeOeC3nWniQbivsPlcz0jhnPwtxoaZTYHKnLi83Lnb2B0@2a2Hb3s4zXssiKJYT4qJ82QieQF/QuI2nb7T@Ok7loidv@PT/L@QvJ1IJpM4nw6EepMgHsH2zsPprxp@Fi2l1zhHaLXTbx6Z1nklL/FZCWBRFxeJTQUXO4N1inyhlK5STYWnoL7yQoNGkrCd0AMUI5xAgsGrWMS564TyYuJ9rlXyDw8O7bvuPYPxQ1GVQkdsJlhOlfBsUb0W@BbFzsaJCm0kL@ZPsgl2O0E71MVqRRM17lFPsBMpqdb4QarJ0@rz8vPK84fPDp8d3hMSxxuvNxxcpmAh/dgb@@OvQsRkvpBk7LiRmDUKwb5rtdmU1G0NjZ6VWQ3Y/0AtSbnXTd7MmxRQ0iDk7S99vzDbrsC7llPhXdOKGa3ZVLc0lk5M3n75@2i/5nz/k90HLImT23/3Jz/Syn/3J/@atuklL2jCW8uXExATnWqpnDg/n5yfX8DFw4qJdoIjVSinwc0XX9REU1G1vG3bdVZTdH2rnClot@26EsRVy2o64UmJYBmpXEx4r4MgLVeBoHCdh7zEElZJYv@JWdTU29s7UJydfEGrb0AzUqNDnCz62za8Kih2lYcvXjMGL71mfzg0NXIpCqu9kdj2G2mbvcE1ljfSBnvRaOJavYpHP8M1iC08CofrcMlmRtlKMlCLWLN1Ub9oZ2gZA9TH54axZR9f6gTHG3gWYtlry4Y/Y8ujP0wUenjwGr4ZW194YmorrSj9fmQkbdtgxSa0ii0FcNsKFyL4nyQdp9/@0m9qWunv/uTXXndedz7TQJGsVkuqlvjZz7an9tQz@s2fQcJrDJOEyiCt4qAFEXRESiTjBjjNIFXkkHugv05tlJp5/FClRCUSZQ5zaBt9UimFU5STqCI73DZeP0XRttBuQZakbrJFla4LQiSdklTtDntZgsG20EIj9HThXPgAg2AwZg1gwsIHC1DgMYbh1@l1PGvqTujkSIrSqe0suwVJIIcP0OzgBtlbCDi5BNxP2bqalKPsEdVIpmJjw/PQiCEMQsIHkCSwXmvN2URH0yAY07Rh6JAxCuFJAf0W5N2GvC2eoEO@KSo9j5BlHDueyAbJW/gAhAmiggkyBjO3IUId2NIHQAAoQyoAbLbZNsun2bmZydQXFhIvcGc8Gn7UQ7MEAiZDaH00gxEmrmM88AKJH7@XiO0iqGEQ72KeIRAOg6@pN0BnwOT0hkIb2Q15Z1AAi2x0paho7NatBVaNhtlPMyoRwj8xJzjZRfVgr8YVgIX61of9mphlaHuyHvpGzQ4oniF0odVJ3OhkPZaUifh6IQjw/86NFlvkpaqigDoWIKgv3it6QDJIjGTnddhj2w2mauU0i5DvAe49QopOh0dK5PHsQ1n7LAy8AAx/lgi/RgIs6ig@gRi028t2KRgMolP8FARaJ@PMILAnwe2PIas78MPUUSooimlR7IHpgoJDi/2h6cNUXk1jsoWpSMKDNrdrBdwWrhXT@KBUGJvBU0cTfkE@G2R6qOdAhXoTxyabf2STCPfvQ4sAHhWYS@NoT@0z/HRQUDeUOI6RR6bSsOUjxmTDkL65TGlxtb3rghYc0ibLjKHMeuM@06osRQ2NzLrZEbg0JSKEuyAtI427ljEGlJ4aBh3l8mqKMgRha9ol23YPTWhXo3smjDe2pwSft1bOzBNTOcJPH0jOAE98cUshCZTPsPvxhf3AjpzlOCfMMk8MPi@cWrKz4jHQF0DkzQJlFz8gbA13jGj5LMtBcJbHgl8ZHmXurGRjaTdS8/TVZ17dSHWwRl/T4GO6@OnqU92O0Zeu10KgIntzL7TURPaG4F2OWK4R2GhpJNH6QmR8SAhsTjXI3JGM6w2TFCisoa0mdAoT1zhlqOwKOMYA0@yFVk@wF0NpP6ABgPoe9Cw04ei7NbTVA5i4/VQPul7A4G32IctrAkbkhrQCo1cAA6u@sQwdwiAplsPz@1AxMk2yI1@B3jnuQxhaiQiaH6YPWze6ybzmonmzjQAcDjqUV4PxbhG@FGMv2DuwPVPRNyCwBBiuwGQjJWYAbEZMixx0lP5yct7aBeIlNXYVUpYhhIDUAIVEhfDb9iz2jR8BAu7oHjcEHxh4PDs7k8nq6NQ1ZcPD7954jq1bymRogkTtKL4xngRfGDXxy9IB3IVL4p@7kiejyc4MRddG9dacPwVh4DWCfTep5MBL4uB4ip91GY7JQhmaBvOoQd0z6ZNQvVSwDYi3P62dPQ/bXw3bn1RJXiAQxhDMLDvP9rIALNvtnWQHZ/16EHBKHRKAQy0aoSfaAnbDl7EXuszJIIrh@MhHo6CudUIrqABJ5FO6i6x5CcOY8/A1eJ@YM0hkG2ds13X1eYrC0xgbG3BqTmIPm8OwTyHghGGGnXPDtOasNW8vJZ9FyWFQi/YPuGh@TDi/Hii3UozhMx4@g/AZD58tMg2zbc3aXCRDrwssDrZ6tFoZxkQw8zDOBbfouwghyCB9M5WDwJjzJb8L@PUalDqkN3@DemyEDQPaxAQIbqSU1vPj1nHb9oyzrXZGGUJjF4kQUOMAutUmmp71IzdS3zq1Jo635GWjsVIYlQK80as3CloDbytYxqiCqGFweploX3I4DjY6cIEgKDBAQDkMAlE02PVTZroeWcWmQGg4LXFBY45YK0CmTdJXEBT4gbjESc8JGwfUjgFC/6hIgCaEsLDn8K@chdzhU9eBOGFciT7MNEY7Z8l2Eih5qatwXlOnSophJUkhmkB2FFcbl4sShkNVtC4FxYp5EdR/HP2N90Z/AP1iNfbUYPmAURfiXQU3GYIIEXQXoiprNmL1ChgoW7pluDBy7XP5NBitIZstJVQzeD5YBO8MP92eilV@L83rh84virZYi5rCvNGAIs4bvFvyfhGSlBM8SuYFyeZhQwjScwYCMHIrkxlBslk82azR4IyDzdYkO4shOSMkZzwJjz1bg2Q7SAba00E4vGD1tEE6xV2QIsBT@TAKYtBEZPj9dlwC/wJtMOLaaZDngudQKwjaEIrY2M567ZW5t2JIx5jWJQDYEK8A6PMPptaEywxPlaK3iEdxUoY8ir8FzYDzCmhgxILr3E5xKmpkpAODwC9maByAvitmWoKo0rww/uX4T8yGnuFPveqZW46pLnvmspf@/lE820jZWAeNSR9qroAMGTWZZ3Zg4DMucyTw2@IjB6S67pnDUiuEbfBXpkFSpWs5XWWs41YW/Iwi95Un83SoP@CaCrs9cXzddwqFGleaTGp2q/LnOoM5tB38@krMVjnIen3H8OykD5Xac4a26RlZhmYkT4xA7TCCLy4IcTk5cDqeIAQzmlyNRdC8XaGo2@ngh507nRTuG0zXot3QtI0Qm2cyKaD@C65YemBPAdDDScrpfmH0/PTNMNHwfpDsyOydpA4nQSDOvu4y4GE9kP8hdAQSDPOcheZIRr1RlO76KfoEycgZO0OQ@qaeLGDqS@APFrARIX0yIVyyTEeVthb7/AL1klQvq6eDpF9576TsK1pKT0fptWUAS8TIMvcyjZGy7orsOmuz48nC/J6@P75P4/g@vR5f0sIv48xV8wYPfL@s86kFBIi4QCN/MxpYdOBb/SvoLKESeaNcxRO8M4p92irWR0x3IepuEF0eQPvIRm8evEWIf7KO/tdXYJh8/12rT8ev3T@dA78Z4xbIFH0wywsXR1MQ/SCNvOdqdlHTvvuOeUFc/FbhPRQhQIwlxmWjPWLomBNQu71oujgEfEObx91ZV9o9bdlq8MAVOLmnWXaira@iu52@Yelzo58KYmZjcMMSPwGFjfjVuxUcGR0xPYfreikYu9JRKAzjSHQeqbamyejZ03R6fbPiUcyo9dBMOWF4sJ5@GH6FNeMUX4PPVoMekEwmcDr21MTpz8l8Mucm7y3@2aSAj/Lxh9ckGmm4mSBABz56qtlFtunr2OeTVFSkdxgRorjycpHRInUIEQ0WXa3D9yPRzSWFyo0laoS1LCx/7GV1jZvX1XisVYRtkq8yvVuTvKnRvXObizU1DmzBwvbebwi5Ahn3c/R6qThE7nNtjTn2FZ6AfjRPZ68ZVTorGGqUkjidb5K6TfJFWkDN@ACeOOH0CTwR4NDwO7xBhWXDOa3gA4SMQsb6JCa1BD4gpAOUGBU5yQM0YrGE0A3Rzy@iPHtr8@xdybO3lGfUA5azjEUSektZBrWA1XNdFVjGwF/DnTEIdWd4XMe24bId3cXZivOkmayZWZY8TdaAISeNZG0/BUw52U/W7pLDS9aekuMkWfsKOBZ9K/k6WQu7BUZw4ZUct9E/YOH43kvW9lLpC8HXTwwvzFdO1qI6hTg7/JUoAqTAcoPUiEtsthMU03cNGNhIqMwybDFeFtUnmofJ0i8H//zzTfRhFwzEOc4tiswyTF0aNGIjBs8Hho3wwwErenItGM33D@/RfqgoCmaTAR0vnobAgxieSC4zI44YhtKKBjwBQeSbtdUYsdhI9o7oBLlDC6VKXs6fqCeTPNBPUXgLIrcXmdA3u4L0YX0tg@AV@G54YuJ1eF5BJ8yOMMI12fQKtJCoL5LXFArrehmXoPbjNURz3cuRAFspjMJricDGeDrIcLQ4h5lNnMlyI6FQ3HBvxtPQpBzvlNh6LyUjrhD0zDXB5B2UDBlDvPOnrytOLB2itsSCMLCVa/NeFo0LxIsxaMHrYpIq73yAQoznQA83eif0PbS7gZPicXaTpbFi3TAUpuVZEudaZpOQWEarV1Pd57lHyus@2sJ6P/U1TDnDuZYUAoiljHLh/NV5D/nd4fJ7KFCHRLiUwSrBevVQelW8vnaUvYS5tcj2agViYJbdTa8UjqIcFiQH7SAmmV/X1q6I@Ljlgwv5PNMI@iVpPyRbpBPcQLfLugWHhVKCe7rseaKB54m2nlBXJRLrVA6FFhlzCuDwgkeYLop2Pa684KuqGENoflu33ruC3eUKjlcewqMCuJdIznu5O7Vpl8uibwPb5j7IUtUa44yclkujal54Arunpdto2RY8DjtP7h4@evA1GHTL5XI6GKPnC/yw1@JcazSOc8i0uToaD1aoLVoWP1qEi904He@NHNffOLbFK7yEM2sQBnTIJWx@QR9PB7wsxs8v9V1Ix@PGKBrAOll0A32JK6Goo@OQbQZ09YEghp/a0gMgoXgL9M6Stpamz/N0OrY@NjodGr7Cr6gGoxhWTbginv5ZYkOZev9vcde61MaSpH/TT1GWsFFD64YNxhbCFiBszWDwILCPA7DcSC3oc3Q7agGSbU7M7o99gd3/@wj7KvMO82ufYja/zKq@CIHt8UaMI4y6u6qysrKysm55GXIAY4ktdW1Z7OdBbe@r968rh@rwdVXtHG39WX3YP1LvK3uHMPF/e7S5W9tS9L@6V68qK6F1iTh82FASXbe9pofgqmq5UHiiGPJWfzARuZPZsuV73e2q1/2mh2uq9cDtvryQl1zPG21IqSptRyc4w/Q57mLXH0HfggMF0jYWi5sWGwnCFkBR3jPa03ax5@32W37bp7wW9r4D3wuMXZnq@NSDJG@NmbMjiyTEBGTVIY71CQ2sayruUn7c3RAYV/SvQGLkkCCCrZzShAv//TAFD6sHb@oK3iK29ve2a4e1/b262tk/oNe3H2p7r4ietfrhQW3zCEmc8c3@dm2ntlXhD4JAIafgxuHXy2B0Lwo5ZGeqNH/DzXduQN0fviVPvbGCV9cum0sGauGyB@njux3/s9daKFmXAZYvMNHkqwKVma8cvHpHc77yfscNp7kKZv2D1FHAcSrnC2qda6PBskHjraSHK0172aLN9xHdiUKoGq/E7h0y/OwoA5yVeFq@p1Jb0FHB2bd4geCxbEBTRQ8INkAZhZWy4hBTCwvOOoPcoNqanT78dEptokSoX1D0pVE1KVlMMa0rA6Cwd6j1cB5ULIUfiO/pw7KudjSUDOpx@EEyqCfyAUvRGnRH1IrOcTnav4R4Vqvy4dfuYIevhdXT8MOmy7vYNY2T9Bt3qavCEH3widHhQGJyysPBTjnEMhcJOD@CbHU6MjA8Ce9IMlGuElm3jXKmSNi0cdWg1d4kajJSiRugJ@S2R4HKlO2cOoRykNfzJYTbecftiQpUpLrDvKfW4H6ovKGXD2HoM7YgGfSZARF2MYlHWG5brwq97y1HJTdv1ehqHUkOP2pU0L6FwOYtBP4ZMAQom9jpNHmmYgtWgOm3NStngj5xJM5t/4jnJ3ZuXTa9RAGttZX51f/82dZEdhL7JKOnyNhRF332hrSs5KvMdn9IY5zFKgeLghRsXvQHI1/6MJNsAd848TRHuTGxUW2fDHF1baDDdI29fi9W6Rlx8R21nhFTfk@tzPFydx6KryiKMHE@TcKidwd03LP@lRe7O3NwiXTt4fiFFsJ8V47Dz8mIMZH1pxXJjj8Ugo@ulTe2N0@yf3xyEIFUxIIEADZKh/hPjIm6aHjwPR8rLA6x7tIjzUSOCy7PUFrr4GlpiVFugNE@8MKnfd3LRilME3Xj299hYzP9nT9@/VqWUllIJh01OrjIRNLNUcemSofLnCqtAhKTnYQsyfqM@eIwzFBev4RdDXoB/nR6kCPYt0/FZdMixLTu7LJNkkWHx9XdHcK31QZrVESxxWEvE@@P/MfMZnlpw85HCiUqRs6MEdGOgVy07ZhaCs9Xt8Bt3w@O5Pf3g1u7FzuZHn4I2va90H4It@zS3bBkWorB@n6wf9wDVia3fwostd25G7BMkrehhZweMqcznw61ae@v8dOtvuOxR2Aw9@IEJQQaq@2yx1fUxi12RgrYcTDRgqh@uF09OFAp2Z9QWZJ72DK0tBgE7AfqbaRt6/dY2OXCRVO4WQ4XT@ZLQqPN/LtvMM8k3h2iQq9BHE2PUFhE4X3a/liknp5ZeAnB2vcsEA3lkth9MTIoONaAb2gPSMhGnRZroDWzmWmZfPwgrgSu6ebI2jiuw88a1jJ3I@jscBIHFNcJcs9hWTK7/97L@vi5qUcWWPA9hAa3aCVN8w3tE@pU8YAy5nLJHrynW0yXQsleFthpQzsofhWSK@yfZyhmJFmEy1o4Jtb14lijJuvjebPMYYVETAMuND11omg0U4IR8fxlPd6hdjTpZZJTEC0yEYb0ZZwrqPjpjZ7CmBrhPFkOF@TxsTbP2BwbLE9xOqthl@7O9BC60KvT4mG6KpK291aV/f@pSmaJRE2G5jMbYxIJ8urKyuNvwZ5uhSme/VnYModMy89Rd0D7@whkMAn4eJ84t7bnmPSIAe4hnajWmwEzVZCWOjPmlETbeTKK40e4yLkQIQOv8YjsOl2rrcZTuM2GLjNSHDpnudWG2BAOGyqj5hb1b@6vDgL5m/U9@PH6ZLAhE1QHb6CV/6Y/DLzIKi/m2yX2CdawyW/ecNjjbGLP1AWUDJsx3Wtsx9Z2ovAqrUIi37fFW9LW1kmiduuYswauhI8XcwjmjNO90vTxXrZYijd1p7ZbVYvsRbKdOItMDVN2TPY88Hv3IcAymM8lMH2wDd/D4Dn9JxwcA5LIxNZ8GaaN/U3cmCK0aj7mwEFaLVTL1uJ077eDptuDSxAn9TBQKecRFeRT2Or@jj3rZL1QSpQn5IJBL0OlnFQ2l@Ki9A0HuoCUBCG9ie@xCQuWGkZTEuY1533oR@FiyxvL6RlrTrr54lph9ZnFres5I6d7/OzUWWyWU4omX7fXDS6H163fzvsXV23VUYNfz8bNyefflVp5oh5TXcuPxJVvcbWcZ@@pT@nvmnpWYM7VCL5gt8QILpyTqKtKLahoH156oCT8CG@an8NCYopL1WLXcCFM7Ebl7vHqablXLpS6x73TEoz8Rkvl0VJxKYMPj2gWJRkjN/PHo1PMqfFTV693peAwk6N7atMQxaYh9OWNO/T7u5W9V4nTOCwAcASmdb35QF0COc9Bmw22J7med53Rx2SOAsdaWCBZc2wVVISpPJ8n4zim5RNm1CsOrWaDMf@d2NZcIXc5GPU5xXhFBGupr/5Xa86YMRX4RIGyHPvGdyLsCwhOlCeDiyH5OhEt6mxRlmtF2E7aMRDHKMniMHWSSsGmEIhqW67jUyvIeW7zAkggcvlXLqbW1zmOObFakONTPKhyuEM2mCic4hEXIPQz4NsGVMEr94DNPixqPt6LeJAvfEY1YjsZVpC3eKWIFKh/qy9s38Tl14kAQvg5WXPl9BGnXnnRQlJsB/lwAW7Okht/XDPArFI6ZQ6NBWyprxwBZ01xphGq1WSi73PXIKfQiv7pFmSL/HarGWF@W7IzSfieWr8FoCV3KSdt4KcTFcvEimVNMZM5Roq5b1IDJ120PXrj0bCaqC2v0yGkhRZzETnwyPa9uv6lsP7gGHWehshLevZWejaRnpN0QSrKlaMJPsr0PJ4plf4S5btRqSibc6uusuLFS456upmjJUmUt3Rf3iA36jf8KPNG2JXClWHCeiIhG0v5OKP3JeVBokzI4GH6saRr/l7WPR9imcj7Mlk/fi3dQR4rz2pdkykuzfX8zgtLB73WKWCzFFFTKSnOYQ2VGVRlbYOpxQmt4HDOz8N2oxxBWSoaicNjJrWx/jKV04uMF5lpNMSK8dbAmjFGYlTiOpeYcGM2WKR6OPlBDATDBKMpM3I3TOGJLjyJgUWuB6ZasYK8NcCpadNDvAy7yK/4YwZ7EjmTLz07cU4wH0vjxbo5SSAWug9Ss8mUlCYwF5GPulH3zCJR3ZNpiLOFxF7sFDis0xMb7DaOwR@EciIuKIykuEX3MEVTOspQNOx7Vxci8cb6R37ReuXSGnvQ8caqgm2Gy1ZYVsLAfeQFowC@odjFTXA5GHRw68gLvms2odZuRZZXcN0SQYzN7DmrBs0eye/gSRukU6Gc2gfkayiIRAnB5fk5jMlgAdu/hmjFiYs/ylmV3kQONGjMPF4WM3NPwfkGC@COfx5HQnpORg8oHQzcppezaI0W0OrHkqa2fR0OlM/TYTcC72M0pT23rL9c@s3ftl7hPvdpsfC4GCPZlb4OLuQeP4kMrIhIJmEZngNXik8sK3Y33JS74SwAOmoXE/074k3vyuv1PKtCMwZnDGjRGnjDK6@Vs6wDL7wEBlywMm4mYYfdvxw25XCHFl0uMSOshANHrsOIw/CL@Vmui5t8V@ZYuLSKbpupq6/8FghoLE7afdwO84UF3AQIPVCo642IKIu2SqLEd88aF167dHEQRdSAn5PY3URIhl5/5DepZ/gky@oQKLkGiSrrtaYwofqaHRfGwblZCMA8JqKAQcBcJd2Hg6UvzX8IB6UbZu7YXdMzeZJ@fR4rNNy9oU/SNyIw9woXi@FOHXz4ulZX9f2dw/eVg6qi57cH@@9q29VttfmB77hxUc4@eNXr/V2SLuFtutya79OHVKVOJVOcYFX2PqjqL28PqvW62j9QtTdvd2sEjcAfVPYOa9W6o2p7W7tH23z7ThDU3v6h2q29qR1StsN9h2s1xayonNrfUW@qB1uv6bWyWdutHX7gGndqh3uoDLf6FfW2cnBY2zrarRyot0cHb/frVYWGWdu1@tZupfamup2j@qlOVX1X3TtU9deV3d2phu6/36seKFYSiLVys0pYVjZpC4uauJ3btYPq1iEaFD1tEfEIwV1H1d9Wt2p4qP5SpeZUDj44Gmi9@pcjykSJarvypvKKGmdlvkEV6peto4MqvCWBEvWjzfph7fDosKpe7e9vM63r1YN3ta1qvaSs3f06E@yoXnUUwhpy1QSDqEXp9Lx5VK8x3Wp7hzRnHL2FvoNNnfyeCENYVqjoNhMYahBoLRFp/@ADoIIO3AGOev@6St8PQFOmVgVUgEbF1mE8G1VIRDyMN1PtVV/t1l5V97aqSN4HmPe1etWmDqvVkaEGhYwPxDpU6RG3Gv1EeMkjMatlONfh7lS1HVXZflcD5jo3cUC9prmFybb1WtM8Bx@9sUMUv48zA7cbP1hp3/505cE55e0TmdlnNKHHpK397SrNyNq1VSpKOKJZZ23KlVI8jWaaMJFeEy5rWt7Z5XnD77X7sDENi8nBRzc4dxC3x0bQkxPrnvBV@nyFC6TTjca7SoM2uvVGw3a@p2QCjW@V0Mfg9@WydRsRCwE7bxz8PH8udF9PEGrjkb7oZEU9XEAgp1D/kai@uV3PVvl8y9PFYLwPwOboKJBrkwtcpZBoZGNHRGuJquSTCX73NTtwwYwBn2s2cE4KzUjO1A/oT@9r9CKTQ@wDSWc57srnsYllNPzPnqlGKmGXCPxHeyTw21xlLvC8384zhXh12PPnzvv9Vsa2TRnOO6J94HnG/kbxM@98qnh2ujwjy9fOOoxAYPbdvIQJ7581yZTul9yQW5bBn8aIf2yDjfh8wKkpV8WH1frQMvNIikMjyVHatQXMK7iTseZ7U/ml9h67ucLyk9LU99fhdxlb0BeEE1ua8I653Cn/vD6VDDTA2BcHkcTXHjLy@VgZo28SZr6mjBfIdO23oPlDc/WFx/M6kYQWspduJ14nZuOhP45jT3L41UHlzebRzg6JTmD7ZG3l6WrJCt1u/eLI7wfUw55m2evYgOZxWqdxUmyUbNHCh0dKzMN3xP7MwPk8MsJ3u@k0/gg/D6HeRlKTCYIMzQ0QuqgHFb2UBzqkFDvgeGAZfp05MjUDZBJNtdGarjvmJb5LayXmAa3M0plwr43xB7DD4W@GeNggzUCaxdj3LnEu7S5Y7qV2jKoob27YcQ@y5FKGj8WNW0gDPupi/VlY1/Kb5u1YLwaiyojxyt3OJQmJB9NYKKNX0ZOR/Zb9jOgDYPYeRl9@0fxGjx@0gzt2d@cGo8qoTmTcCUvinDo6jNaNPtaQTxFHA07VTE3rCqf8tkaKx54@Tg4dg8RGA6OCIC3Q8U0CLoV@RKarZA3Ylwu2@iKcCucdgFPSHKvfiXNnNUdDKRn/IfrdeKVQAit0ciJUuw7rsEyWD6EfC0POBJl@ih4M/19Ikxnw12nHSdAjasWcAH4XJRmq0Iq2r0wU/9pcNMRuNyJqxj99iMDcxDvmImyYvr0Zi30NkUD3zsR8@MBuD9uZGQQAk@NgIz5@Q5W0C5e2Ti9Tti6Oe5JeszvIKD1XmKniFtzs6qnDyy7H3K3gxVa2nDXFKtylouqlbNzOeNTTlmlqK68eBikBZxv/H/lFPgAJBzxz6YVorU5zVkGPMiMHtKul2ITTCj0m0bL05s5bu0UVc5GZkP365ssQikBvAJ/b7eSgIn0l6rlJj4s8E6tD9oIHf@LYJmPy0S7rzlgRs@MBzsMWH4Yg7sjoGhNER6Czq74Imso8ZEURVBJpHUZ@BiFu7RyRlqfV6xB7PpkEh4bYH/XEkb0np1omR04cfGgM4@byOfXGnRDKne9rtrBYfrHed6C7iMrkWEKXR4yVZr8/pKWji3YTjo4/sXPqvT508HrB5VD7L6T5zB/qEwmz6KdqsGyS3TtPM@JDnlEL/BGsFVo55g9uUteDhqi4JxlnV1WGmNfw6IY5dPTHS0WVWY9S1okm7JaUibiuVtXXr5JLCKpdhnpMQT8INxess8n14N4hHH7X/eFvmPuxBOq1vFbomTQGks8CpZNqPfbx2BxJ0wf9gE80qCtwAhJSoigHaaGiKs3RTzU7ab2mVOQdE75LuSU/Xk/IpEZbiiqKGFfXTsy3mqXOBJWWtWvQ0FlocXmFUZm14bq5czPG3kKT19YqddILRcpzWUSUH5qlI55EboZPH/CkD/nLDwOMHvqCO269BAXCWLPiXvW2nGP8oFPw3veGrfiZKK1kWu4Ax2@89en3mBfN0aF2@9d0R4E3oR1AM@@P8wyjkflT/6LX2Op33HO/77u0T4Mb@LFIPDxO@BEddj7sXwccPogTWrFMrUn0LP5lxA0b3sN7yVLMNVcw8gaZuJrCaDipXIibCD45hxJgFE@U@Xsw7SMtLPNkJSpkJe1PWR@vaJfuLPu4OKuw3OgDgBZwG1MaFGJDOmLDpJjxaelWhrP7MsRwPFNZ5dp3aOwlMH5GJOJrmATGBplbagnxRmBndifGx62x02IfhEM4WvK2PYTCCTL82XERopmkyAtoCjxXxbVCrKjcoozhhxAPk7vJvfz0X4w9IfAT6Bcfz@KWWYzAIq5tvC0Fsl/RXkYJF1YP9FlGsyQmKeaf@72Y@SEHoRhPQ00mT@6iBmv@0KJIu9m7xZUYkRna@CDKXaZBIqcxsTGpLKgFm/12YAlSGWUKdzOs9y39WR78uMSVkzMIpi0NORND@i5SNYlKCII7pV4bR1l8Kn97xCwvf2@vTRGwPEvlLBaMOZMyKxe2QPFlfsW1Vn9Iwjg1RT2t6rEQjPqDhe@k3p2yY6Zntlm0btr2NxWBhdnKNFkutpi05QkeJyVrGp8ppklSjDXNiIewfeXnkM2niTguNzDeyo3JN@hwF80ivalwUgn7uyVjH5PiFTR6zUQTDinGHU5KS@H34wY1vHG3BNEwZXvVYInRgMhoTOQxBmqKTCGVvp9CzH0a9yl6tIhyqLdFtIv3z51EnVaSMy5PTVLCySXoCcftMNokuTRoQ/kCbuJkhRsKqXDBOXYmfJVXzJ7ByTASBCBWxV42OoeSE9yos6b4iKMDtDMNaAsVIYnoaSOu4RA6/Q8Jxl759eGO1nhoTLLF05JAGoeQaFfBue6DZOzN6fW4MWYot0hBQ3wGKcIW3ZJNF9/fqp9tC@UjCFKak7Wmb8FBY2y1RNjQn3hSY4w1cFSVLpkYUcmB0GDRQGOBdinnHU@2q1j9@UPheGg36GFEGwj5nMHPki4Bd96rhZDaKDJuTZDF1uSW0War7IYUiRhK3kF@PRRlqcsbVwLgCcZUvlwkCHBrytjjUoBd78Q5L4Go7iMqWC5iWNJH9ooa6XnOSAdRdYYnK7EchVk5nsVhZGcCoYXF7DwRIrRmmZ0lgkIT3UxcYjmezm5PlIMWxIb3heLUFbpXkjQMe04IyEGfC3YkUY6LyiloDubEJyt2IjHkb059VoilFqZTiT4hhsfZ4nTqWiGRmqh2eTlZNFGS6GHHa00kEinsOMKhVPi5f2yaEnd5HuqExjYZiVWG1s9GUG7aZdK@LfdroNbZKNusMQy8uGW42X41JMRKwin7/Q7Y1QJfGcB3@0@31mimGkx0rAD2S2eMXTKyIeQVawpTPZqFna7xtBc6KDB72n5bvTvc2Um4fT2bGEWjrjdcKRQKYOKzuPN7o1uNoyS/n0/mzrcvO5384PpPw3dneZb9nschAZ6bHbRHXUKDIsj1h@cSGQI4UFbkzmpDVuz1L9vteAgG3FCi86jbJKf2hqB4AvJDpZd3h3wAxCD1BPsJDUT7Pqlw9F27stDUUMw1FJWGSvBVytyeEXnwoQ397PCmioFBMBttJpq37PLGF8wgiGzCncXui@0vkXpy6rXX6fQd9R4BiOEpYO5musDOTrxAQbLghpGtey8D9kfrKO/K78TsipElzusAZyYmE2fC@IWHb/wD77w6HmRSxx9TNK1Qk5fQzCX4p3ZU6jxla2fx3wFW@JDQ/q7cXXeQaTKdpjPTVK9HcPREGD0uOjP3PoksNp@JaZp9OzeIOhvdHDtroKbbvBYwvuy5e7kld2QPiZs6GRfboGFBYGic4HPl@0rA1OxfJxavRu3290lFDgMgHftDElEiofycQOQ7AB6BevgRPeFF@89ZGtY7Uw5FZIGDYB235Q4KNFDAsh42y79fZyqVipofLC2pSmWTHrJZVdmsqG182NxU2/S@ifdH5eWVlZLI3G37C33cNB9v1CbB4BPOpebFcJteKa0MuzFoa6OL5/Pleac03yivb5SC/HFlE2b99PT3f/uPv//7f@Yr@uW/8bLJL8cfw0y5XC4/3/wy/@imhPfj7dOF@bPj@cHpwnkJXPYP9hrer42ybqQ@mhueWWmZBWJfWY/U7LPZ@4wuqkxMwK47/I2ky3OVbgb5tP4aSOQolrHpphf77sGO8oy28CbowPRWnpBIE9AJjuOpd5oeFPBoviFKEi7QA5XycrdiDu7hDibMEN6qpLUnHl6zXnmwaYk8KcAWl2asrN8LvB5OwK94zSvNsyyXfv1RQ/Nv/uOb4HyzP1aLJxm1WFCLjlpMpfinuPqMvtrzeR/WuZKNtgOplEMp0dUC1AxV4PNCj/cPHGtnityWNc8hewDJuKngzGIF54S7PzaWkYBrwbk1h1CcSo5I@JIJRdJf5ns31C1fKMdNKmFqwwuFht7FcGWxG5Wwf7EEcgNRBIhq7gpBnvepStz0sUUynvLmi@5ri6MJMWCQ9eDVDo97fKC5aL6ndZ4TeymEOWL1efmKubEkxtCMNlKk/ggBvlCR7WSBLQkX0guWaHnHWsnNFCvsePs084muw8QbGd10KfSHijGBaHPHCTff03YtWpFbrldUyg@vV2JVpaZ1v5UVK9K97Iz8gTZX4NoxoL6Etd3ISEKPMiCBIz77n98eYXxQYDxFTXWLBMuaqFYfTZeR0NOm6dTBdk5ujmJEyH/M0Nj@OjW27TxbiRh2EB5gpEJVvrbrdwLtdWXIxD53h2eIDui2OaDaSO7N@DwP0VenMO63Q6RzDJlVzqPxTE1JD4buedd1VHqvfzh0JzWatmjlM2rmbGohXDABCQw@XfWs5hmEpUW6S5giYVNYcwjBCzoTHR5N@jYV2pygS81Q0G5XMAgS7MSU9L4m@mqKjhFX/0AnxFG@JbzD20gtYlnyQtNIQ0rFzWZ4mN0aOpapIT52woGTsgTVcGQaXtCFLjHRdvnilyR5Bz4CdN0pbQWoTRFWn6F@zE7nXs9NTE6DjmUM/fMlJfMixjOHohRtJMvESS1GEe@AFa0jPya9QMjcZNwZWXOZzNxJoMO5pePzCDv5DnXx867ywwB0HMCMLUPUUc8XYTk1Q0UxMHKqxpr/BKHdcc8Jv8m1OwErnqQzLx7k7eOPJ73TxcxJ7@vJZ5sx0SLZzLJZldaX2UZi6bFCM2PeSbwarbTAuBo86SUznPSU2LDESECI5DPHH/OnX/OE0EkaMelP0kKQRJcBk/z99eUBPn8LzXQSi3zamrMXbdP5mRdFW9Hcyr/oQ/lgyy9hYTaVfExP@5xhm0Cxne7vl2JyEuTXlgtPlotPaCd07o2zQ@8S8202uDzzxrSUCLCdpann5HOCGxKEuBkHbok@jqmdEtZEbE8CbaSkRage5lyPFbIVlckJT1B@ojK7S4WJix3mcXH5iA2/o4jlTF72BSWqgzHuy2D@DPpd1OMGkGvT1iHCkdAyEB0RPkLNArIJvnIXh9pmuCywnVNObcF3KwOh7s2nY7NFr9/L6sWanVsoYRENq5nOWmGtMD1Gbw3RxAid14uphQequPHi6d/@a//39Ci9sZx/P6TfUfr39OpaWh7pgd4em7er9EZ6HdlWb9KTPO2B6fHp3/6Hym/8ieAgZbJOfzZWDKzVSXojW@YiX9Mbq/RQXF6mev/3r3@lNszLjg2xWOcbjmLESoYiW26PeZfSVQ2tlG3pQiRW2DALMETDkPbm9ALFqPHyWoGP6dJaq@LK056vjD6KnuJZMWvEqkJykmH0KWhlJAXKqCArII0KRVvFdDeM2gaYN0JTfXqYWw1oB/BJq3OEVYaqGw8DqAzNy7aIOjAjNdJ@Xh42Ci9SoXrH85TRKSmZJSS2dlrWrj0u/R8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ak5j7)

AsciiDots code:

```
.-#351$#&
```

Other dots don't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

## 352. TeX -ini, 15900 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubx b t c u c 11  .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMtMtMtUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)                                                                      or 5<<64>>64or 68)); exit; "$'#{print(187);exit}'$/"; #   wWWsssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
#  
#dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{
















































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"ullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>805在ｕ92=1*\0C0<?ML 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
typedef int known,macro;int x=!  '(',y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD40XHh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7apStUp17@1LslggCZK4AgEWQEpkSaro7tntddueWU9P29Fue3y7e9az7fVEjHdiZ93esWci7P044ZhP/gHlx8aGY8P9D3rPOQmAoERKVW07YmJjIRFI5OPkyZOZJ8/Jx0FH94Y/@1kML/bUseYDy5mwieFNWM81Tw1XZvfm7K5uenktKwgYa9cdTEeGPfEqQoypjFm6PZjqA4P1TWtiuGnmGQbrGJZzBuEaY9tTe@oZvTq8ZRmzjTN2YHfNHkBgE@fEsM3XhgthOcbuG9bF6GLCus5opNs9j41d055QaJ6xpzq89KfdE6Z3vImrdyemY0NQgbHntqWPOj2dUfSxa/BERQaguieUZjmkxNhjx/UMyMHpGp7noGcZPHXXdB7tPvnoSnw1wz7SAamxZcyuZK@q7FPTcHtXU2jsk@MHD676ZtlXJMdmD66jpObY7nTiHEyuws@z3YFh60yTy7J2NbAAxJwYVilTyiwFQdgD04Va1P3aYl3dhlrBOttixmg8mTOJ17NuWWEdekz32NSb6hbFs6ejjuEGEb2J7k5Me8DOzMmQTYamF6aj2N5Y7xpSz7DMkTkxeswyIZHT96EAaLvHToz5meNC1fowHduaQ0Kja/ZNTBLgAQDxSkyGBocz0udQmfYEGgHTmQdoWEYALSnEIP59ozMdMGc6GU8nDHDrmZ7esQBoZ856Rl@fWpM060AYEJP8z4aG7TdaACcDiGOHY/XFlFAzFm1b7/VYBtor4HFiMBOoRmhVWDYL/sxxgWoQK8DIB0btl5fRmEHdQJX3nQrLZzIQvh/6ILa65Tk@MsuoYaANfZLqDOE@dZ2Bq4@AGj2DaPrJwVPmdR0X3uCHcXm/uQlMV5@w7W0W339yP87qYbXIbkcIq6jGzqEKYkEgO9WtKbSQaE04UD9umFrAKotvxCssDmTRMiyXYznoniWm5YFIaqYMDujnWlaFX4FpJZZToafk42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiliA9fyTIN7JseyaonHHDhWn0frUmZFli2xQpEV86wI9zIra5Abgs4xtZyHXwF@AK0MqKjwy@Y4oEW7h3aKbW2P9fWRac196AS@y/IqKwJEwFcFyFoJIMAzm8VfFn6E1vIVhT0ZArWH@imAlyzzBLmOETIerEIFHsrWlkKcD1krz94bYvZAOiBavsSKkH0BKJEDFICyWgmyz2d4QbyhYVl@sqGHyQjbYgZ@gHkR6FAC6meAlhkkZhF@8A58TQMGpgG30oABaSr4a@DOYhYQrwBhBajKgk@voe6dQEY8H61HxAfODWBUpDYyKxWJBBCgtlgW6qzActAQstgQ8lkG@AMuxQIDflVSWSnHSkUG9CxnGNSNCnhhK1GBT6qAj4rAoP5VaAAq4KQCtVUAqmbzTIgQW81iOKTNQlogjZqDNDlwQ8WpBfxBOmgZKmSpQp6aVl40QsBNy0N581lqnVoBarcIYUA3DXDVoDlpgK1WgnBMWwIalrDxFuNpTggd6QC1gs0d2iEQIw/4EFyIC26tmOX0063xUO8YE7PLU3b6mLSA3aCAZISkGSwePHNITUAlA2CwFwD6GrSALJAjC1WbzWH2lwJ0YD4sR9kfcIlPsesjM0OGDczKIVa8aJMJO2A3SeCOy5wTWJkFbROGi66ObA07uUFMKoBjTmQGmcAYajinOOYTp1nKxiNu1HFxiIeho2e4LsO4IBd4aeJb3rTjGa@mODgt8OoDIzSAX/Z10woRoM6pT4irwjPuQX7zZbT7rjOiHjxCvmQ5znjNGABc8AwBPXTOjAXqCyapj8cWDEXgb/CREJA500lYIckmmitHCBJhuu7QBICUFbBw0zW6RHu/6JA6C8x@GcUK0@p3sgjlXmSMyrKxA/zbwzT21LIqMHgYXZatKz3jVEEfPo4tj1@IQzCywfjkg@joIGgg5oRFCOmOJtOYeRzUrOeMlovGmdZBWPShiaONdabPofb6wK@MmT4CcYihzGHDCDmCFsNrEGsCBD4s1gHrOXZ8EkI5c0EygEKHJSHpA2kyMUcGiI4OJMEazxHSyDIJs84cmjJRKyeTrMgxuUIoWbhKKO6Ri3jwzgJjaG/aRaph3qZNLQjGHg8FJ9fQe9xPmLis2dTh58IgOfbFYxkdGPEZohaR4mCENYD6vjjTJYg48Bu2BzKZJzMThVdo@QOnD43tzISyg7gESRewu0QEJEHoNZO7skAkxwY0OrGYybrjMQN/EEKgeT7IlGBcd74w2WsItIYgl3WnrjtnszHUhDmCWJOu0@9D631tjIcAgo16rDvvQveESsbWI/Qc4kjd8XIxF2@bBsSxUdLbe/o1NjCA7CAF9FG0xya/KMB4TEUgUug2lxBsHSiFReiO50QWABOm6DuOjP49x/CosTjuSdj1MTPPGFDXgH7WXzCjEUo80EptktR6wHn87oXwMUNhZWEwK78VfGTY0HW60Cqh00P1YZ3usj5oKBG5AIU3vds1xhO/nTjEzkw7IkQdPkAhinwlH5jsDYXNu2z7SquBqGHLiQgIKFQi6mNfttOR1/pqEIgMtrGQ4zlnsebXsocYp1dyF19inCUMXoprcBhTl0CJkpjEdIKsBLmj2R0iL5wgtyEhBnqbO71efPCLZu@OmNQP80ZsVGA7gqyEXojHehgS/KzrgOSxhbDqSx4YdcnjFtC6N1oB2QmRtHpRX1nRZWCKtwEdObazAioQM4SLUZZDqC6oMT5DrqFbYWOk7uIt1REy7IVmjgMZjKHjseNCz@BMZ07qGVVZpHX5Wk0iHCuSoNUvD60wZMRxwJ/gKAgJxhboctTFsKeCuKoDpwAmxrUO4HkOzzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEtt20CJV3fnHAgUD4ZnyGjOTNcFNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6F/IWZEc1O@vZi5ji96bdszZVdWmi57yF55wqrusj1qNC0IHdKJEvO/Fk1Xyp5SRIFFxxhOFkvK7CBEpkgxVnuiDogSDxANgNM/mdjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmMf6@PJVey@AD9sNKMT6Nf0VmUDGL4lCe4S@hEmGKDIGKC7IGdAJwTRvVzudXR2AdwDVPTZHqVGIZOeqpwL8zLsXpiXTwjEJVpemWfhuV1ySJFRDUuA0ankNEgsEfAdKUEJRfBQFH9sRQ@S9ngYyTXcc2rTJAZLcFEkyc5DYR8GgAQhY4LwYXbNSdsXV@7cCQSXjVoNGhtIU8A2e8momhDM9sjAqSGyTNKIn4k8cZ5NsG8kklBejHzJsQGxCVpqrc7OJ0MXehy9XwoQCcgq2NiSA8L69fzEPJn2rla0jZ4YScReB0KT2Z2IVQEGf94bajdRNb5EVVAl4khVbLyYnkBfa7zkixUq@tFcw0Pxt@ajEqnhBGLgt9WVJOJJfb9Fg96bdy1fJOAu6OycG3UA/RN/diBkRGlfJgg67bWeyoFgd@Bw2NPd44c1vy/yQKVj2pUlD8vp6hZ5b2J0MUj76ODe0e7R19orYFhmp3LVQzFzpQIOtdOZNLCnSk7WKptRGAvA99s3w8aEy3FEwQ9mkjOLiErzLgwus4Cch0dfuUoSkISQHJQDuPF3RaThcUDoEjq6N7wyCLNBKgVZhkmCuEw6YAHM0IGoY7ge4PN0@vo1Vt5VpMa@P2JmTXUOIPBUDuwgnYyBVwSwIKjT5yMipQUp1LRxlnbhisYM8PkIpearyJAoHWkyHx0@2D@qEVh/skKiKIo3AVlKd3sytHlr2jOEVXGA/YGry1LyAnGUpwnXlQTudpcIvKhbtgY@AEBdR3aYZI2ConlDwH3vatnIV@qGLYDeCcJVuTIqD3XfF9EIHjjEdVHlXTWKUsBisAq9Vo5YYejysNXN541irhwdtrqLPHtRoDTTCuNAIDe6EHTiSegjL6RIX6z20X/26BriHgmRoApIAWaexWTKy7ME1F4kk8U9ZQ80NMcy5E@J44lMTCpKPJhslbseKZ@R@Pszc5LIJPlTTUJcyH1390C7H0T25wFpJoOUBtTFcWRy@7g40vWgjdiO5QwctgVpuHQYZAhi09pi7g4c@1oN6eiJRY3h@grwX5y40ccw1pivSXGkVFF1la/U6LZ3BlxaLWSRSEQhAqVQfPkL/VQHci3K/ezg830YRNR8JhO6M3QBCSJpiFzo6kZ8yYNJkJHs47OygOFay7XeHgRIkcUOLLTP6MKEu4vglZ7EMWVlZfyVKH3sXKP4F878StMCH960wBEh2cGTp48Onuw/3v2sOdHy@aX3XKZcAMJBfh2QheQhpxv21i3eNbFYCC4GfcPF7gVcYAoKSjAFP/VcYNwyRpE5AmtaDV@lSnzsDO24l7xamDMMlb6wu7wJPcbOx6P6CUHR7lmojLh8qQ/Hc2w/w8lk7FUUBXr5cNqRQWlVvug6lj5QKB0MDJalqKi6HBzivIa3KgUg480NnoJPboHoMKcZRN0aOaC80IIhsgaW4OBp1soyB0PQhXFV0XCTctiCqTRKDzQE0JWVsGzEgOkNaOs/g3oSedP@QNVKvF2rGS2niEG0pe4PcTf6BqhOCRitgBTJK6@sead5h82BSyOkq0BiTN6iSQ6P4VhgMRAkadYU9fyAOMQtcL4UeQXR6NUUZ3OBSyn5TK6oFvIKqGWgpoHMKuGcmzTSJ92hNHEkgCc5fZo3iLTCvtfV7b685TsCZEHu@xCKmm28aDbtFgjozTuEGy7mNeathtpKVtn1JFt@/GQVWu9S8bDtBh7QdskJTZOebA0/6@nX2VlPp97VY8pkNPbHHGnMHu@CIPXaAX7dM6J9DxMo0UBlaymugpHfKCsmhCxMKuANKaVAh4KRFpqegnhJIPSieAgtB/hWJAFbzGbwcvDF8QgfQaUb273pxD2a@Ue5BmdLvTEQkSabu8ilPZwfnMDoGLZ85NJQucik2ZkRx3l03eOzlZDIXzgN0oOuFkKgWflwRtoOl4ShEVAqUs@Bc0C7wmnT4WKWEZV@aGmQIeGEkw8gQdi0ejAAPgOJeUF2eUF4TuSzXKQT2zmzEVrHYCWpY074ZL8zdXEB0exFywbRsxqPA9CocBG@TiuNHaPLZ1l5YioFKIE6GxkjB6cSQLoiVmBQEXS@Som6oIcz1tCtMhIuwwB8id3dAy7WNfh8kTRCJQqa1D6LT1xlV/pc0aXX0JpvkK2w8LvRZXaq9OOAAMtrxjRL4s@AknTijCjSpzTfgoH3AnFXGM8nQygxtDBRrzljw76q83GNMJGs0tpuPA4M37QT5/GNjY14JV6Pp8G1A65tdO2gKwWuHXJJ5MJ4MrooRZpcGNqgFOjXil82AsizZAvbwAwlh9fmOKE3KpVsK603VP@p4TMJVQGUh9gSPgBOPFmroTOZFOtnuGYD8nuk7HvYdp51XXPsk@BjEAj4u0@DLBEB1HuU5l2jirrpzRQZ1VxQGg0UMRNuvNnINFvN82Yv1byMpzF1sqrXQD8E5jVJjOSB60zHILg1chUJeFuyka20qp1aPBPfSiRKkgUZ6cnkh6VkSue0TsQNaFOJZjMOJPWp0@gOXYI3S2vJZEgowKNvgpZhWYm4fF6C/DvJVjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7p0kQgeFRpnBHgjemDOgJTQMWGIi64pEIOkxSnsrp8b4@HcjUYIZ91AysYZ9MUGANwngVw8yiVf8/RRgW5J0w/kXh4PhFucvEN5aTzn3F3gmDaVpe0rwbh7KvVHzkRXPpFBaZIjw2V8I65IEoyEFMIhUbEfmx52Yd02nKkXnWlcOQGKuYPv8XAKzDLY25OGVmWOBaM7dFh88y5AZ@F6Dw4luHQl8QWwAECvK8MPmShKJbhYAtIF7dIwgS/S/haalVEJCc56grn5fGH8Sg5zq1IalsGMzIHtuIYEJIEUAm1JoQ1NQp35u2IOaObr2rqEH0pDGirepgEc8YHl6ERbzq4j60HjUSQ96OeQ5MjoCRbwjz6wR5nXhWv0lC2BVmkddwgjBJQGObEW1tbID1Acb9yTJzNIKiRwwI0Gcu0OhM4z1tM0rdDN9ytBGLYKIPYQKgm1UhtU3CBIUiEw6VfyPp8WCnT0J4f39/ncCQ22OLziPFp75PSmIFf6etORYQ/SbB/ak2k7IxPIEKR/fWIdOc6Ea/nwsm5mhivN5mhq6TTnc3Va5sZ0XafjWDQVdFPSRfyp6@mWziehgtDdTx6DrP/8@FlNrkQiKfrp6Ma8cR5ydbacngfRNUdabw2WhzzeMMXNvIjjVrBlDtmMH1DAgKm/YQ7qKPAvon/QpXANxfcvof8IN8uBrOzPItBr6OlHLFNE3ECHu4h8z3M1c4n@a3WwMJ5K8bjguMD2XNXI/3TS7y95Z8n7RELWZC28c@TNN9It6YhRlPI8Eu6qW4oTBVSgOOHmuqvxfOYV7jUYGlawgngEggmuksHYbqH4BLoJSuJ8/5sBgvQYF0OIQ@MSG@uCrOldm7aAPjWWeGwhtkH9BMYwBSUXYVNh/hR3lXqK7fhLkx7nng6o9jR7sl3ni9moOrlca1P45PtmG0Bs16vBZqV10TCneDyMRlAJN0hBxaT1@2tFDXdjeDSnLlCSquApoDXMtIzUnBX3WxdxxSMy9JnYbM4@zGifgfqBO8027ygDo4oZrqNXNQiJ@6JqZ84kEOwwFp@f7g6BnbDUbJmUUD9Tu@9YPYkvhkG7YFyNwgry9yKEO@D8jY6G6Qab32j3IU@KbDSyb@4a3CtVWr8eIbLTLgQEveScXZykTy9YA0a2U9kbW@akxS7lidMeIkkmU9e@uiePi5quq889wd/KUmO7Rx990si0OARhpOMCV4nX4izY2gnyMchDuNcWXLghZ2JOaMCnDQcmlleVAakZrYUA@gCDZ1BlYUZ@iRD1C@NiUZa@AQppwkDMvfkozYzkpdy39MnEsHmb46uM68nNl4P8bGqU/Y6/tlBhGVqAAQHUxDBAscqeHd/fPzqSoeV6ifg@LtRUoDvq3SHIIesKHVAyWvgK@7AXZx9imiRq5wJ0NVAy2n56aNRVaPSgZkDuyCIGhpsAzySusXTBm5a1KCEXxHwC4baq7oRoFAJLGEkoEwGrrMT/uc01Kh/PCrT4FFESyJ24UwHamkl5apuvZA/GExJPIUqc66QwLNQ2E8TUNtUktR7XHOEKMShSJBtCCRoNJr0GpgeRRdZqVflSP8RFPcsdIHVFkaqCdgDX1KDqa@ANkgtB8JPX3rAXjYxUbqU2V4GiPWT@5l1e/ghchLAM2jNWZruZoP5@rSNzHPiSH2fkz0lrvrJDvcI2uUPkU8sUPdgXRUyHtlEtb4da3mwFnQxZCc24YEEClhDzt1b7bZbCifODaoPJyCORZOch0TUkObu4IBqyTY0RDcGlMl4Zl4GSCYzpkQOleeRvq44KAdRb/f0i2GebghhoU8sLshjCJXXl9IoQKp2K0XRcCDTtE4eWdUJXOyOreRT8wtSjE@t6yr7pDem2FDXEgcfV1mHnjTp9uq2IQKsb/ro5edC8uS/ygqyoK0f0oCn0FTkv7xVZyrZj9Kf2gBYZ0c2kV7fElMolitzvdMx1UYEIuP0reK6IBkwK27Mm52Q12KeNMy4wHgHj4krKouhXtxmxJbrD6DCBVP7zv3y9B/S/XjtDGChwgjF0tGHoxpqS@msry0@KL3RbXbF8HnxqmToRhly3gezqLhRJt0LHatC01i5JMPyPcOXAr3Fom3gD4fCGZsYx5wt/wXN1JqvWzmxgmd11ca9su@JZ0SoP6G89IgIXgkyDEhHr4pVgzPhKS0STRjZ2O1LB3ihGjZnX@3A6mfI7yKe3VqI5xt9NfdOPmcnrHdUADVHvmMYNVe7qJ9OeI41PBqGcWlgRd1F6WuqVQBzwV33b6FxdfF5A1xzAOBs810VbDG3KGT1uaxWePfXGUoeU7R5/o44wuiEH1@L3dVFM/4BT6FhPNdOi2zu2RB86NBR/04OCW0qlCNHMK2S29M4cZZDh@7eycAMBcJxaN5XKZNesII/H69Ojwkjpy@XVqWdyl9Nj1VSAwretSnyyjArsb2S9pVZhuDJHuiVpvYhzLTNftf/gWtRw6ZLSGKe4cHO6suYW1McBqTu1dHfhuqGJL/AIVgvWTTz7w8ZTs@uAODBmalFWtWDoiAwYxDKDHXCLjHDXMN0iuxzMVWTsgVqIg7gUulazAKc7wZ2ha9rUOzA0viMT971GGonsrKNU1znD31rxYQiqKb@vHtFer8TqHZiTZHUtHcbxtcPB0hwgzjHe0lDPTM@g22rCnqxEdNK1Vvovd4Fgdi86W3dbs/ZMy/HYM7rfRKCBC1Tg99UNOkpLU7clmvOOum/gQcFWhkWF6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2tT90@8n3/@a4cLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3VRAd9nJxG2vEecMQu4pN@Uss60sHigGuz60u2YNMiVLKCp/RW5Mxrqyc6fPg@XMMHetIGwwd4zmJ0yDdYYJyCRwTl4vYP09uuZtz670bU7oGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR/VqVMi2jvmcKNZN5dxbVt6bG1FipaBx2vjDw6PENSsa7I5Xxi7HpT8jjGgCeQAljvfY1w3fCGsdpfLuRmeiW2TVuF2WWmdoYpO8xqs5PwfEUHddTDOzpeKlWl7Qz@@hmkg3HQZd2ekvYYcj78qHSLZLSknzuGfS7UWPiGh7uA6vlMpmML8BEFlaWXm7SpLJh2i9Mfl/KmHwWOS/i4mKaG3GuzoPIEt1puJYFaesUe4pcLiu2aRuTOd7fkZt2HMd6n5oCptozURQDyZJ21N5UY9fEHf@sCFtMXXg44dHpr5u04KONr1sCfVBpvqnSoys/71SbEq5tjnDdafn15umbyDrSbbngmW2cE@J7bK31sqQ/G6LKJbl4Y6/jEqrTMSydP2aF3E3wynL2RnjLTMNfk8U1XL5yu1hxj11hSuM5EMvsgZYyNEYGvd4g5es9NC/gP9ZGmjn4Wxc8M4yuMts3uusijE3gCzbel5aKI8LSxLFBv5rgdj7UUyzcMOr7ruPAweLeSiIfjPSBwe1a3MQpFxMWuGmGq3UL5@qpiwrfKNOFZAtDBuubBHSqE2PuBc@VAB/Pu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50Dfobev26l6fYi1h87QHhpDvj08fFvXOaA9TrgdkptQB6wHQ9yxNh4v7WSP0tNyLOtd6ImskTNKx@mvxGkfz7jiAa33gjvXOxDgP26dvNMnnHegY22vGRpTGJc8Z@KMDYne1kW1cKKH39fx0GAt@uedQbpRzweKBM@fF/6tuuVAdybjMT3aY2vq0Y2SSnQ0@Ta5qc93oNDeR8cdyK@dUUf2PWV/ewotga9mMR1z0h3i2XDeso2B0@kOzduQ7hj6xDZPlGDKh7@@k@6KlDGZdB@9ZcsE8rpzGdtLLRr@DB8H6yrdnz3iw1rouEFeWTVDR6evpbF@0vX4bCi6WAUnhCO9kZ/RrtAp98qrqTlZAI1sWQqnd/myBDrW4e5vklgrWdFRiAUb9jdPrG2lJKSjQC4ZGRB41HXZLm9ni3SxbJbf1iEULSVhFNl@8j7k9rf40OygGZm3Bf@l9rW0N2nlIGcPpwPvOsPk0/U9ENHwtn7agrYsR6asYczSbf@xjsyapeBZRni2QeaaGjeuqeRvXFSheKol6Y4JjzY8oOqma@fQLHPs8TuT@muX4vwtS6CLX10v5LSZr1am/YrpGX2@BIKu20TEkePihmOQQaQurqTjDDoycy54ccZlOwNg6pLFFpGDuOvElpW7gVZXfzhmSp89MQY6bql@ZE5wT@aKVkFNdtUuolthf3Wqe@ZXp1CydY0NDTPwZUg3eoIf31bAe6wPzO7DpYoIkfQJ7G/o5I@l5o9e1@vibGh6uKMpdNwwMYVNjjdibHVt0BtWxLw6bx/apFh0IH7acWXsVXPrzniOh8Lm5LppWt2c0Cyr/1ynOq7b63UjEmfT0Xjq@Y/VONCeqegs9OiE/L0zE4BLr4C1sqFuTVbPVEemXEEK8wfFhXOdNP65aTkD9nkpw0BoAyEMhfMVDeceDM9PcUOOa69oiZT3Oy574kSH5PKCvYK6NbJMMm1zcvNszmSCm3OCJxaGjxx4EEF5hHf57vtCkI5XU@TR7bL@4gTyLeM7tLxnztTtGugMzYpE1QI/V2Mv2GSMBzccNItyFtXSuo4F3Qsc1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhwmalQqQZsMRX9x8/T0ZbA23Kvk0KNUD5m3rWfOFau2HgSiMzbRDE1vPR5diBLnGfm0M6oh3Bt6TZRZtNXWLX951V@s7TOQwg76wwAfOfju4bXVw2vDXvJ85jx3ZgNBoDoxwdGfxo/9JGj9UJMdkjPLwO9Ondms0zArtmEOLShj42OlC/1sL1LmMRB3xfn@hrhiKaGyT9L3Td2lZMq2O4X9CkX8S9TqVdRuihMSPdYn2D4X1QmnS7XCTG@bilPrK0YuONHcfmd@K2GXioj2/mKjAU0O3dF8pl3G@/NC@wUj9bLurhKd8lYvS47Yl1ZXWNjmPx@w17kmyT7wnQXdPwlEdoyoD8CjkmgfTl3chDijfykIVqBJLsqe7RIv1qVWMBUp29xxagoe52HVwJ8x037M6J2B@4hU2HW/j5xoEOEH4GHEvvTn1Di7ehZY06I7qtVRgitXlkdPDwT4eMdkz02fXK5DNDvsWCyI6u8Jx/wK6wUxdY4iloI8nbh60lPWqZquaYbsSp1y6X02YdyTaN7msdZ80cotdibnopHMqsPCHnmrnqSDeiWWRFpwPtK3vS8tY1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclN09uBNZUV6yHTkYGLzMurMGtFV8cbUmGd1evpIXN1Dck36Qe8JDTvx@VDaXet5Ing4f/w3scKDMLtQi6wMAKs6/YVfEB@6tr@411a4FPHm/TN2SHgjacA1rETLFYeksCD9wx0ba0rBNSePbX47MMgsu9q1CN1TCILtpJkEbueGJJhn0pk7212vUQOP9ul7KLl04nRk3xzB7jSID0KjnmF0fznigXUKG/EzZ6qwgk7K@T87Z@riHsWcAaQt5yJNPboqYy9pwePDo/lsaeuHJ92h3g64poct2Q/QStlIlNSX@huZL2Tb0frmd5EufdMlfYeHcgYYQ29@YqGBA9cmVt6rJ339M2K6oq@VgvCUGOyWkB8ePz4UWpxEpMl9oauMzKS0eC9Z8/SeNLk42crg6OpH0Dv6DuztckP9lU1uaL5PrdpdXAd91yR0zpIxwZoo9AYH3LzK7cKV11nbPSO52PjExg8kYN775h9YW0hn@in5gB7ISuvJRR1VFaWC7lkZGc2KNuGGz7X1eeJOUZu2aWHwh9rt6Og5JBV3Oxq6eGmFf@rUgzL@DsR3i@RmrneWiemBD1jMESXont/X8RUVV1H52d6H@qV5ddW1nKEVevDlnP6DkvJhq@8SKGXNIFWJZm37iMvSiNg3QrecHre9wRnZ@02mJsAhN6FlR3@zLDnui3RWtZN4kUFUuOmthujfG68w4JUuMPnFA09r1zjC7fUs0SXnMlbMj52I0n29u4d3JbgyKflzbE@evKcPdU9tDVyc8QoxsY7YLyQjL6QcN4KDd2tXU7tuQBKuxHeYLy6P1fYM93tOfZ8dvsiHB01xaGdbAiHsPCNIhmWOTNXjVVdPq/1dPU2o9vy5oc4nPmSHBy1QeMDevutf6GqmQxZGMKnmuGvt9RM0MFZAl36HM3WRYOOD0LW0EW5RQaP5Ept9JExw@0ofDZ4lVK/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Obwko3hOVuyO9aGHqyrJxRbwCYvyGM5eUw@JFjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVCN1UkPINBSlHuPPrUgYnQWlh0XevF/Hx6IL/WNlaj42JmxsPnY6ZW1mG3T7akmSP0Sb69XB/O4Xu0vaWgeMf@eDvq/M7mxorM3qsv14dQJzmZGUQMEFjOKUjEdeDlxdIOyDzGvbA5GYU2T1nsk9vK5F86uCO9ZVZ3jfH96fj9YgCS0Qr/le5@FLET0FVds48dg9PxC2k8xUqP26LW@2/TpRl4XwgGhF9eLwbNKrDZ4oWyXGBxWdPl7zxzOjk8FnEzzVms3W6rjRbpzquDFnk@uQ4t5Ttdv3F6QpirT9mBFIGsOHwuVb84Tzu42fXOQFqbcPJyApCPtbtxUTpUoX1nAkdMFwZ@HQ@o92TK2t6yDevrQpzVzWwJX0exmHThLw9pd1Gu/nt9rpZxGPjM1pyAOmHTbg0woH6ZpWMWW4YYIhJ@LHKo6kdtbztpX3bKfwYMj/86cmBefREwk6lksnlD3xET7KifdrEJtpn3KRTqxD34oJt@CdFIUAMzp76Z2PRjBtorgYebhUIxKS2CdnUamq@zHbwixoVkEuTlCN6kbGsIK8G2zz3j31WKuol26gxsSIy/@BtaPuW228FuGh5EsrEpBOVbU4gZDM4NMroUwTsgpGuC8K1ms/Am6xEj89X/WO1gNLm@dODp/vPjnePnz9rZFqX/rHboBC2DbkFh/s/zPZEKLtPNhhDuTVnOu5tQXb0mQTUkb2gXAxKdqVotaWiLQol7mCazXPbVhQ6eaxIl4CfJPLcKBSbBHhx2EGJqX78Q@cVfgiYzjJDFXHQIuUJdVZhmVUZj3UYDzZtP/zq518oFD8PVMEPBGHGvgFeaIEDx@n5OXoGu/0Kcnywe/Do@dE@CxBcNJozszcZ1sp5bp@ZW0OAeuqbtBWrxuJ@kjjUVa0WfxAHwsTlOKvQWXGyjQztHKIF1MFT5n7qLZbYJPhAwXhYKcp/@bpyGZdxV3ES4sYDpOKQLTR5aigbGxvsGBoJu3908Mn@EUP89@@TN5IIQbBjPKj6Zz/u8a8LBPZigk8juSPi4mSXQ4geVg9OcC8OmSPNqeuO138giaz501Hu8DMC4XdQBIG@MgHt9oxMvV0xA5Ykyzz8g06@lbYgI2pCgUVynMBGi2uux05Nz8SD5IhDHw2gLTd23PNCRv9ktotff8JvTOn0qQtAfWpPuJEh3yRJDFqaHLKcNNskZPmHMcRIxPj2BjT2jgHjOvNsE4aLSYV9AS0RJ4kr3NCAJNXj15IEoCvkknBQiES8ZjHNU5qu8vbX/pkyqDJwT8D9bd89y9yDt1/x3/rg/lXufqFgQ7tuYW2BSxQhtIrol4AjEtIfaR/56JXNjTssCIeG4AK@yswRVNMpUR2j8xz4XQJ2vICTaHwClQbNDWrMN@rA8zPcVgLNMlYUBZsUypoybak3Znx/2xXzjIV8IacqgKR0GgAke@oDPLjLASaTFegmwqk5rr0EQWZ7e5uJqHAatUKV16yyab/Iii9DRDchrnA2ROQaDNJAkkUKCKv7yWDwSalJTIrcK67GkXH1HBiVKBxHL3y3fUKILAHE4jQy0ED3DL@PNnHngZnRDn5RLPKtjU0fkKTCmESupCj45hCeOBNoPtBJF1/T4eYQcH8nHwHRfp/Hvw5I1j2xPcrXe9biFG/wUQ@/r8nIAziobObqYBqtW/FTBPEMQVTEVc238YI1J027pfC2yaCZ/mBFY7bB/cvKYE2b5eXevW7bMXHVMiMSi919ZjuoWT@AwrCEpmhZRS0kF0XK5VYWyS@Rnw0UBy3LXEB2wKaAZXQN8wtn7O3u7R98fPj02TX7hRQzfjUa8P36dqopyelGK3TEo8VarpJ7D5Rnj@89CCpigXQhwo2B8fslUW8qyWLCDEEuDmBcLdoqDK@Wbj3Gn/Ij2lfxzWo3oUaJruGhZt4jX9oELT2go0xXM9dKq6iVz9@E0gKeEgG9x8@hXkM1kTy/bLS26007Fr/eElZ0hBcxeQs7Abia3tamgo39euGwYOF3O4/xo15etC9mV/dFcTOLZrTwGPzEOVkYEPM9IgGR8gbZAIsUZCWIurb3HXIZfWHmTuPfFeUGt6LmhCIIFzI3UTwC6jj4RClykYWRTt8@5RBUM8vsCIEZJ26nMjCnF5qo5CaYEknB/9QDzzjhf7R0VpnJtOMpkURuR7DS7CaTlwG8pAAdGqW7p1NQCZ86Y276m1a27xuB68gB9gsKO6nEBvt4OoJ4fXocGbTKAJxbgsRAyXiIKpelgEv4Fi9nKbQpCvk10O6lX3B51MsnZkl5aMx65gB4eyKZBo72oaq2WGgVEwtNVjDtuEh1tqiFG7viR3i6OEr29zKNOlsgoDd0GVRuY5aIn8WTlRbkj/7xs09P40lxVVsiE62@zdLeVVutIfpF9WZOok/83hkYQl3FLcrl61wC/K4C5sbEgu8Olcvy0BPoO3I1lNyfTdxH4AQxItEf6WOWmNrcEJvM6DXRTNhpslAl1bktR5ulUqRQwYMCZEYp@@Ti43dCt@csodSgEaCvZ/fw8docs4Yqyy1wUyZJtonfA9sDiQstECYF0IEhSYXA1rAJgZoBGPFOIvMGDmkwHOLCg8zZrQimzyPRZKyDNKFSs/odFvm@27LkKJbLFb9Cl7limUHru84OZQXAXuNzgVwP1PVttADNQP2VhdiCkV/neDHKN8YReegbdwF0YhH7q4HNFwawFtZRu0MXf4l9G/oKyAeVyvPjB@1SUhFZaCRm4Jo9XCzgJsRDFc//6At0U2UparzKNbqPMBma42tzKzRoFe4BdRjxCkuNRclw9VPMi7apqje2ej@hXwsQM4cDgH@Yrh2AQ7uTwTTPirDVzP5nP8OPPYuJTVU9abunqXg@U4WbWs2zPPtwsylJm41M7e6mDlrU5NWsCTq5spW7f2oM@52DgdIURZZlOUXZOj@PP9h6ar7QCq9ml1m19OpkrBYa8qtZSyzV0ict9vTpZ2/ab5Li7HT@SmwmNPoY8d7hhajmUNGPVcrsfKeQjZ2U8ZueTNfzJ2wGeis7Ya/hOukz/Cf3617EraO7039N30KKiyzWbOJHnMWiqCiNeAv@Sd1/CRdX/Bt1uS7vtN68STZ0fTKbM9M0x16vBz9nCBKklnzGIN87wOkpvsKa9CQFiq7RrL@YR9DzcKtreLJSvttGH7LsONs1BoPpvj43pw8mjz//NLie4/X6aMWERCuVSkhS46p3pa3nY0zLaH/2k43L9PnT9vaffWOkGBv4OMTHty8fo/uZmv9wY@PDe/dyubSmadz99POnX9vd3c3dT@efNvI7OSmzsf2nf7KxoWnbmrLR8jy1FW@cnHwmapmcKP/Zj@Ltp0@/6nn17P/59Td1FW9FuJ2yIvAJuLJMBSfeS/BTUcZ61yv2OgatXI3N6a8dC/zPN5ha3yn@1@8evopNYnVN@dSF5yT2KlYoxbgTHPCWDd5OY/XYNkYrXMbmSq1WA2fxv/47SF//GOBgyHwbbvV8AKswj9WlGiW5iNUL4FA1DfL9v7/@9QiGnE3USIwLrrusAZeYK2riTguuLbq2BTS@J2UUJYhnT4YTw2Fq6Y56B19MeIGHbaCxcmPSjOEXctnhXcaOGqlUqiW3JbjkFzhHpKiq1lTVO8ANpA@3ajVpi3Hrgtls/g4aQk7SjNbAgQHTuMM@/ce4Yqs8qz83uCMhVti4@/J@vQ6FytazW/UUXX5Pok5VLImOc1dkafYyDipIo/XyEe85rC5mSpqYTqd5d5ohqaTZoiXhxe@xWOiDXZZd9VtKAlF839j7x4vt4/Xn/9uff@/Pv0t/36Pff0TrhHbP7CtbEOkUukQdrruVSrdeF@uueN7E9zq0o0ylVCkp7ctmYgs4UOuIqZmPLuL5bPwZQ/YPAwBrJik1XJRt3c8e3@uxhXed@9Sjfn4Aj0wezC8FOZaoRu6QatfiwdDq7@OUGqf1loQCUU1qqIV8S@KpAizrZda4C9UkasWy2Kpree0Qqk4VecUNNz3mxEAzLAR09PGtL8pWD0MWb/WoV6weJKsv4rxvvADduhBrNJSWQQNC4MfublQ2SpVCRVPaoef1i1WvexmG8dSLncbCi1MntiBoLGyaV/2CqghfWNCC2fvEA8kowsFm4RVxXr3asxsvmt@HawP@6B@u8BXvG@Tje1OU69cGq6hbWlbJf1jY19j7XQKME6zb6XRedzsoBugdvaurE32qz/S5PulMOzPWYSBFsSn8sN/IUiybVzdjd9jaIgmxN40NdsS5UIulgquZuvV6Lstt30kOB3@S5MxiQuwf4aqrmsq2YHzKwA2EMnKCzox/qiqw2DlcrTdbjTdb0EHrqW3ijq265GMJD7l9t5WSLi8b4K5W/f/teuis0sVdULjWZSq1/aIOoseLeiMFIF/4IGWJEVC5XW9tU0iYmZ@bH7zdAuFFSm03tmvOHv0gCVxSPOfEC87dFgDeXkL27t2UDK67AKC@Cf0xmUptStIGjo0Nf6yAyK16KigV4pAAaeH8/Of8gaIHXfZy@7J@2di@vNzehv9tul/6T/C93L72T4/FtSbOIryFrKXZUOpNpekziha8y0odfWSlCY46PCFeI6uVWg10wCW3/tv8l9OLe@iDKLdkwFqIbbGtGNrKy8a2hNjLt1/@L/hrvv3y91FeZPBnVITYOXZrZQu1zTJXOuHG7Mc2e8wvG9z4C17RBz0e19HT5jcbF6QU5aXMKnzOP6GWCkkZB@C202/j8XuZvYSoKLjBuMRErVQQ2yl1rrHYtlgo0sj0i9eueDz@T15q5WKcT8/gqfGXnuc9juC2wA4iV7WMKqkXdW4YnX@q4hdXXf/kF9ddQuyizIwKUKXrMU4PIQbNJyZJMErVt0e4qxjXRyRURU9rn0nPdyWcO9EntPrV5fMCtYP9Wrlc50s7m0@pq2zd34K7Cv/7G1AK1uxD3Ga/1h2B1NvsZ/NaE41ox6TOK/x79Br/2HEX/45e4R87fo1/RxP8Y487@Hf8Cv92O/h3PMK/e6/w7/EE/54P8K/5C9msWhU3z4kwKbWsXm7ORCJQNbZTb/7CxJ1XLMNumL2W/xmYbK7MkrHmLxgz/Bh4hXv24z/9zje@Ea/V4lKcPq6RUx2Xqckq0B5K5MWrd@NCrMY21U01Y2W6GbWjdsBhsozLMsPMUO2BctJWWcZgmXlmzjIjR@2By4C/DLjMTJ9lBixjZ2yICKHgmrQzE3T14TGAvz4AcuHPxE1yHTXTZZCRhYIafZcPwYProt0UGizOxJcG6JeyKmfkgtnCr5k0xJcvm8pWSyuXmIxNSm43XjbjLbR7rZVzrDM3Npov2yzmgYZajSnNpsJpAsUlkl1ettv7T@632wqOM83HzuHi//BwFH298X906Dw@dEYO/B8eHkLfMOqpuyngwHfv1oAj@4@dWL2606wQXw94e0zZ3mnWsxK6Cylg1xr6pd7zWkCEZ32jKcTPEqhcnKF@Uf30rHpaJfdZ8AqOdnURIYjGHf4TrjMYwwJ94wyu0zN00Bs6zz5thi7uUD49A69PGWhW4T9ocNHXf4B/87@t/8fPWZIlGq1k4vxyO0FXEv@SyfPL80v/Xk8mEv5LYhv@0APeMcn5ZR2dFOkcXI1EspW8vOR@cE8ktznAOmSzXae0i3jA92NhlpQtvyX@YZ@QtX8141UGHIe053yG@lFMrDJ9sXGm2ZxlMslqJzDhj8vA@gXtTkhW6TNtm52G2vrTH9FnGnaSFCmfq1bVLcZftJxWreaCt2KpWi0FL5uJRPn6Vc/sqAVQMHK5ZLJahZedAGwGXkOwJQAbvOQBquHpXZ95nh8c0gcMgHPkY/jlEM4pEhn6/Al@SSsuVsQ7dxL@F7p3dpN37mjlzMVF6DMeg5e65NVu90y33Ub/7MWF2BZpH0s5D@@Z0sWFmimn1HjScRNP8BNskFVCUtmHWp1yLQNL1nLFJPsHuQBYfnu7kKvXCzlwF0q4ok5lZ@JmPHYeDPfFJOeN8U0FqhX1IujdOCZ47PwyRnXMcvlkArhrEuS@yxj@cW@1XOb@SZYrJEqpsv9X2wC1G6QY/oeiWDaV2ypu3QWhFv9W6xTIk6vnRk29rJ0bFZw2v6x2/a/dopUA486dbBloWMpUm0K7fX/3eLfdromiiJIQ3NCTuLuAxhPceIOqN19uNbB8rUr1LrUDtZRnUOE8jhSHEYKVoFYUbSuvlpAUgtlHIyBQfkElSm6wDUGjJ96EMqfvBniCvoKZ468HF@uBGjXAiw1wCpSZzKKLWYyH073bDSM5/PJDw1dKi1foY4SXEHv6aHdv/zitbUsspj3Y3Utrz57fi6n4ml@8U3AW34/2d@8fPocETx/t7z7b/@jgk/3nT8HfY2eLK@D0/n3xjLpWvJ@xT4Uv3Ne6YejG1DDaZ9Pp2Sv2hWm2TahBawqFcAYu84w24D7WF@Wowq9revoXX@jumC729gffevuD/@7tD7/z9offevvD7/30y@99C34/ht93@PM7/7acx/tPv/wXv/v2d34Inv8Rfn8Ev5/89Mvf/Dr/0fsfw@8/R/z@2P9F4vGfALB@5adffvdHP/3yV78Pv3/l/75//fdrP1n9@9431/8w3Xd/9@Y43/l38Ps9DiuI@53f4X74vBb/d3i8X/3@29/49/z/T/0/dP7w7W/8Md78l3/@/T/9z2@/8R80rfSn/@btN7/79pvfePvNb7/95j/V3v7mv1Ez0dvvvv3eH/zVH/7eX/3h/0j/P6b7773L/9vv//O/@F//4n//iz/0fz@B378H10/@4j9A3/jbP/gB/n/3D/72j36A///zv/7bP/j1v/2V/4kcv8Ud/8@/@rf8/te/9p/@5re//Vc/@frf/PpP/ua3/uCv/o9f/b9@8z/99X//@3/9z76Bnr/1k7/6o1/5y2986y@/@S//8htfrrl/68b7l@/g/@U/gs@74/kucN6lXO/r8@XPhc/fhxqLXKCdQOv@5be/@UvQwH@Dsbff@jEeqoHfmv8fayrF@TF/@/@AQ7teZgzJgAt@v/72W99BEv0PQCL4D@n17fBlKYS/fHvxAmT97RWJfvmnX/7LH9FbzKjUaS0GB@ySVkptgVKzVS77g7a/TANJfmkZWgjAz@nbyKGWwr6NvO3tD77@9kf/9O0PfuvtD34FB0wpV07vpiX1ljUuiJh/h3gYsfAu8TDiZ5h/iibOpNRn8MY@8wM/@@wzoX2h4Omtuxfg@xl58YvxIDzd5QcFYeiPx73YBYu6fWfGd276vmHOjDVevmzhKir4Ye4pEji2Ankon2WzVDAPzWbBfDRGmm3xqWm8ky8GzwS8Lf4XzpnAUosZbPzaXDiPSznxaH4W3CnkIZvUbBaZCCdBhzDkPrT6S/nmygxLMJulZqD5ggNySEHQvRSr1WopTFjj@MArR61eYoRKKlWDcmNqnibdLiGI2T2CAilrqSPW3qrNeMIUwqsH5EgJ6HUkqpqYKtXuQ4a12X2GsBA4gX35slYv1WZ1BPeG0yM1S90jnBBYLTWrv4H3GsGEdELs/htApVRLpeolzBALyasn3eaVlKfCUdlTLOXXATxxE//OXcY@FNWS2OZSIhKMx8Z7ahEbI0J0CG@mtvzi0H/gpN8WEXyDsvJzYTx8hwTSHS6jYgSAK0myLDP44bL6DrsLwTMOKkXZwiPFIaSoRVALCD0YzgClhBTVb4peIP9Ybeu9LwSGhdnc3BRidTErHspEOkVh7kmFTjTgJj/UQCpMLJRF9DboeEeAC6SvUv6bcVwuizMOmH2Y4r@7d7fYh1BMei78BCalsk7OiXEo26mUqAH8upMSXoAuIkA7JUAXgjyrkbaTEtJpxuRaDMPY4eGhjwR5vKgJKWjmWlbFd1wkmk6nMUghy2k5nfafMj3JQ/YdMoX6T3kTiUtfLmaalquCylRl6MWi@o0Kei96vnnzBmqFdk1VDkAlZf4GKi1XokDw4EYsLGseHAPScmWBq@NMLeQYS9AUKlxJlhRYgm0lBb7XniMRXIm4VirFKR5QX05sBfvpCio1B5w@jdUR0eDiWmMpnwwC9w7Z3uHjx/tPjsetFhMM@hKz0R67TtfwvASG7T65z89ZaOVCMtZoIOjjioYMRtivZIgZH9w/OnhWYbzQfhUkCLEqrZb6xSyrQmw8/nQ75u8nEvErY474DO@VRdkSWjkLSWN1IdY1ULPAZfAq7SOpCo@9wT1nBpp@WhTTagHVuSRNGjPha86UoQ1MbjAD@hSevpC3t4kCQv1cogUJdEJtFYR63d@Jx1Sh/mz/GBIcHzJVy8hC/TM2kzFD6VKoWzXLsAeT4SZuaRObGTFSps1GJo1/WjYLdzVXSKv5YmtjwzqXMM8mVds57k28hNdzCYvxAVxM@EBgH4AXXJAHbjhk/m7Pg8Oqv@UOrU0l@L47Uc1DN0sKOFPNwQnjxQWIQuteXt4RYhuffz5h9Too1dLBAyEG3GLIgl1nktmThzJVc2/qGhQ6YKxnfmLi5@PknumNLX0OXQeoEbu8vOwDpIMHTKtr9MpT9PB@2SWfDrgvZ7oQsyuV2hs1VxS0k0rlTVbTBPAQthTc1rYBDYB2B2wp/K/qQSbZbEkBTqWKIjyy2ayAs8OCUDEERltA3mRqNYm3wWxOpR0gAn6RQJ/VtPDy484@XMTNZnhcDIEANpi4LBOEFXmY/1YQ6A2Ihnve6Pu3Vb9zZu7cyeLMRTaXCacoqMTsEupmM5vLIsWF//9avmjhZntcz2bUbWUMTh2cuW1FB2cHnPltpQNOE5zlbcUE57SeVTPbyrQuMGGbG55kaNeiJk6MGdq55X5i3TOsvoxHh2oiZaCJ274h53qQsN6r9Zwufay62pNN/Gg4HkflCXI5serYaBKthsYR6AAvSyTPhUHtjA7NCkZtIKOVDdfWLaEnd5zeXPYmcwsP4ViOW4uDXBgPAhbQDRBIcOZrJ5vNVRqsJY@d8Y6g5YuphpqBkQR/aimtpTeMnWKx0pO7lqG7O/lKvpTu4fkefzVrJ5@pDOTPHj96OJmMjww69LOTK0MCtEuFFmR2SpV8vtVoiGKqQdm08Bu8nE9JGxvQuQ29J8ET17o8SSu1IHHPdGu1eHwnq2qSWslmSpfCgnBIcyxhXcCkKSxZGul@7rOCiu3YwHUqaT1tnhMVKv1@/3LrPLV4EfRzib8BfS4lPd05D1@rUiRehU3TkrkIBB@9D@Q@95fxKqKWL4nVRnXxXiyI1dalcHdk9Ewdz/o0M@fXUxWAO3OoMcioyYTLius4k0rH6DuusYiYVQtBRI7Q9Qg58TLMrpnBHM@vZ1eIRJqdX4eSy4uXYaoALeHyEujOiQ39ghsVrdOW2IZazrX2gRU1WtuBuVGsm9iLF7per0Mln@eKWi6fy2vZQiFf1GDIKecK@RJ0s0whk9c0AJArl8rFS2jRQkzXpXotq2UFTZO0rJRVJTWL/7c4NPx/9/ga/Gt4h1RZTThGmx1PYCyD8ddmj/Ds/8Rhxw5@/WXA7hndNTH2hjptHt5zHc/7e8S5p9snPOi@yQ1lhkEPdfwEljcyJ8M1MZ6PR2juw3D/0SDsjzqAILImHuEe3FzLcVZFKLLnT9eU8nFomhqIwW1TQ/Sjg48eHkeex/u7ew@FArt3@OT@lUfej5Rnj/YfHIevRR4aJM2HIL62/@jR1Vf/kTt8ftSfOi7@hAeHz3OLW@iFZ1OFHFzLkUJvAuLf8JWkPRjmQTvKFwOHKuCJhjugsd7xnfnCwplB56f84K3phTvs@RnsinAcnMbVGXK9jsG63KoLqtBkcc0XsNViWRDGzHbOWDHDeo5l6fg97/4GeA51PFlooJRp0efoMeszx7V6Z2bP2BAe4yHGsorfTkYkhIcAZDTtknkjkDDQfmcPv7SNK0gda2qwKX7lfo0nPNALna45GMJ4eOYEEYSOrjP4ve8F6Y3oNbnZY8LzIL9rIdb16AIoWqL4UJ/od2OlRtVrjeuZSuXOHfWpK5azIoyOujcw9mfQaNlz6ES6O0@XxIksPmByOzbA5QaroOaccV2vg3rQAGEaRtKdnGbUS5n8X//2j//uT369rNXUrWZmL7O98/gRy1eAQYJ8yUiE9MVMmRQOrVzKl8pZrZQulUu5vFrI59OqlgZdrVgGcT2jltRCKV9W06VcGcSCXBlC8@WiL6QqgVSqbFUArN3FD/puk84iD0E54cuG7HVCT7KYHr5PmWhAGlFA9XBCR7W3zBqMaEzNsGyRAUSddVnswYO9zIMHongPX3ALxV5GFHv4ki9lMsV7omhQyF4JRRzR4WlKaBpNnPCXTObenihOOQC0Ki6KQ3zZL@BElyia@LK3@@AB5tPHFw3TQ7QTHsJfrOClCNFsfAHZmQC8CqFBtF2eT44Q3ccXzBJDHvCQPQgTxY8CdDDkiEfjAB4GJd3dFcUD/rK7iyF7VOw8R/Qr@LJLlyi68ALtXxQH4Bi40PNEsQNO7AWi2AVXd66DH348GQ1P2xNdFOecPEggUZxRbL17IortwB@z@cTHJo/UrdCLykt9l17K@CeKWoA0RsuGL1lRzIUvOSjbw4ef6MNJzxjwa@7yZxdK@vBhVjdn0/0HnY8@6gwGHXe@u//REQbt7T0E8WA@dTuDjp@w04bLgVR7DzX9ZDS/ekGpD9rtim6tDPpKu53T7StB7XnbQAwh1SvAzL8GmNGovQdBew/bd/VVq7oEsI0MYATPDl73RvC8p3d4UHBRED1nnY5YxeaPsjsuxWJPPAFeaqdHetd1qvg@q20wFk/E0/NGIdOqUgAbgQyeqV5ieD@Bdx0nZJLn88aslmnVZrWixncE9RNic6blTTG9MdpRy/nKhr6jarnUrIKGIpx@nMUldYcl1Dtbr1niSXJHA3lcbO7sSGJDbe1oaqlSKL7YmopisoL3nWyxAhEz8QxjeEs2iq2dYj6SpFhM6YpWKRaT1UugxwRG9A5OlLQTiTNDP0kmEV1U26EIVFY2p3Ka1X5ilp7VOF5snqzOamqV21plmWuwemjYe9qdOC6HOABws51MBdfCE6JaLomQv6IkkknUp0lhVoTFXstPv3p8cnz8GXBCJtT96YSn/DvkVf/1o4d78sFh8IYGueUHqAM5rryH7GophNuLDryOQRuQH8IQCppV4IfH8VzHkvdpuxooUkFAYGZV9o1jyscPl@A8GzpnPGe0ZlAlC2t212Bor9zsMb1WB5feYwnCiunJMxq82/V6rV0b0YF/KGKQ6iuMjHkvwBx4HPfQxgIlP8cjan5Au5a5rHZqs9gM4LRrTFJfjpzeSy3VrfbQTPm92j1MXG3Ds1M1aobrOq4YE6v9HbvG2NT29L7x1HDResjB4SaIEnhuLdFnRnKTNfcx9h7qDJdS3WX2ArMn01EChPJOctkr8oqkSXw1KPI5HaTEnRKX1X6NJV4kq6/g1d1kiZ58L7mTq/YS91g7CT6Zl/2XfaaxQq5K3w9OICToREQbLLOerNW/AtIPB3xSqQAifh2fAEzMCcCaPQrQk2PzstqtWSwhsRlLEnly1UGtgakv8LYtiWJLkhoXLaEuSZ8Kdein1XlMr3nTDn3bgmU6qpYpVGfgpxZz1SFUrP5iVnVr46lrVC149efW@HlRvQrkBKoBmNcXibe/9PXktpSvcb8qgbqwQOBoy@3arGqjtTxoErVsDQJSjVwmDXo03IppGOa1QlotpLPpXFoqoi@M8el8GjxBtwGZImElRMbEdGaWkdW0aqjpROal2XuZTJ8kQF4hkrFkeuLs29MRAx@oJGyV9ApPnSVT2pbFoBYcpm9L1EyBU1SxYEDzIRub6SGCOjJ0i1IkkxLLbiWszQTG2TyejvcbrUplfzb@KgQlpFc7hVQxk3qdTFYTG8maZ7wS6lWhjlyFSj3egDbrTzsybzpqQB2DSy1qlUajg0UsZtLZTBZKZ7YvBttiXWylMxsFFarokpF4xDjHiM7EoZCz8Bu3Uea2DKg6taxVBZmmxbIlTSor@a18hk/N8ZTC2GdrSEmWaIrB2ehEPF7U4vFkvIqLAhuiPwsMvIz4WByYavyOuiOC/CVWxLKGERYskY6/ZgLsQAK7FHAKguXKQuxcuDy/3AaFWKFNlCAwsg1ySXL9rhCrMAZiYNO3xqRsMPa@ezNT2/UX/NnEXfcAVyCztiCC0p4pw0QljH2CJ/13WBwQ091RQ9OyrYZWhIEMmGMQFVTxKq6DxHBfv1wHCnvngN92qo6H5L7C5nM9JQUT83cYG6Q2BSpz7Oqa525td3C0Ww3e9nCutymIoliNi7HzeCx@CX9C7C6dzNP4yTwWi5zN43P9vxC/G4vH4zipDoR6EyMewfbOgzmwCn5lLaFXOEdotJJvnpjWeSkr8akJYFGXl7FNBVc8/cWKbK6QLFNNBSekvvJSg0YSs53AA7QjnEWCwSufxwnsmPJy7H2ulbKPDw7t@@4Dg/EDU6VcW6zHWEaV8NxRteL75sX2xokKbSQrZk/SMXY3RrvXxXJJEzXuUY2xEymuVvghq/Gz8ovii9KLx88Pnx8@EGLNjYsNB9cqWEA/9sb@@KsQMZ7NxRlr1mKzWs7ffK3W65K6raFBtCKrAPvvqwUpc1HnzbxOAQUNQt7@0vdzs@0SvGsZFd41LZ/S6nV1S2PJ2Pjtl7@Ptm3O9z/ZfcTiOMP9d3/yI634d3/yr2mvXvySZr21bDEGMdGpFoqx8/Px@fklXDwsH2vFOFK5YhLcfAVGjdUVVcvatl1lFUXXt4qpnHbXrip@XLWoJmOeFPPXkor5mHfhB2mZEgQFiz3kJRawSmL7R2ZeU@9u70BxdrI5rboBzUgND3iy8G/b8Mqg3ZUev7xgDF669d5gYGrkUhRWeSOx7TfSNnuDCy1vpA32slbHBXsVj4UGCxFbeEwOF@Pi9ZSyFWegFrF647J62UrRWgbokC8MY8tuXukEzQ08J7HstWXDn7Hl0R8mCjw8eA3ejK0vPDGxlVSUXi80oLZtsHwdWsWWArhtBasR/E@Smsm3v/Sbmlb4uz/5tYv2RfszDRTJcrmgarGf/Wx7ak89o1f/GSS8wWhJoAzSUg5aF0FHqEQybs/T9FOFDrkL@uvURqmZxw9USlQiUeYwB7bRI5VSOEU5iSqyze3m9RIUbQttGqRJ6iY7VcmqIITSKUnV7qCbJhhsCw0@Qk8XzoUPMAgGY1YDJix8sAAFHiMYfp1u27Om7phOlSQondpKszuQBHL4AE0SbpAtBp@TS8D9lK3rSTnKHlGNZCo2MjwPDRzCICR8AEl8Y7jWnI11NBuCMU0bhg4ZoxCeFNBrQN4tyNviCdrkm6DS8whpxrHjiWyQvIUPQJggKpggYzBzGyJUgS19AASAMiR8wGaLbbNskp2bqVR1YT3xErfHox1JPTBZIGAyhNZDExlB4irGAy@Q@PHzi9gu/BoG8S7iGQDhMPjCeg10BkxObyi0kU2RdwYFsMh@V4KKxu7cWWBVq5m9JKMSIfwTc4wzXlQP9mpcAVigb33Yq4hphnYpq4Fv2OyA4ilCF1qdxA1SViNJmYivl4IA/@/caLFFXqkqCqhiAfz64r2iCySDxEh2Xoddtl1jqlZMshD5LuDeJaTo5HioRDZnH8raZ0HgJWD4s1jwcRNgUcfRWUS/3V61WcFgEJ3ilyXQchlnBr6tCW6bDFndwSRIHaaCopgWxe6bLig4tOIfmEVMZNUkJluYkSQ8aIe7lsO94Vo@iQ9KhbEZPHU07@fns0FmiboOVKg3dmyyB0j2inATP7QI4FG@KTWO9tQ@wy8R@XVDiaMYeWRGDVs@Ykz2DekTzpQWl9w7LmjBAW3SzBjIrDvqMa3MEtTQyOSbHYJLUiJCuAPSMtK4YxkjQOmZYdAxL6@iKAMQtqYdsnv32IR2NXxgwnhje4r/tWzlzDwxlWP8koLk9PE0GLciEkP5DLsfX933bcxZjnPCLPPE4JPDiSUbLB4DfQFE3jRQdvEDwlZw24iWTbMMBKd5LPgV4VHkzlI6knYjMU9ef2bVjUQba/SCBh/TxS9hn@p2hL50XQi@iuzNvcCKE9kignc5ZLmGb7@lFkfLDKFhIsG3R1UjU0gyLjqME6CwBnac0CmMXeOUobIr4BgDTLMbWETBXgyl/YAGAOp70LPQvOPEraAdH8DE7SW60PV8Bm@zD1lWEzAiN7LlG8QCGFj1tWXoEAZJsRzepAcVI9NMO/IV6J2jHoShBQm/@WH6oHWjm0xvLpo32/DB4aBDedUY7xbBSz7ygr0D2zMVfQMCC4DhCkw2EmIKwKbEpMhBh@mvJuetXSBeUmHXIaUZQvBJDVBIVNCR5dCHyxefDBIg4J7ucbvyvvHHs7MzmSySTl1TNjz8jI7n2LqljAcmSNSOMjFGY/@DpSZ@qNqHu3BJ/OtZ8ng43pmh6For35nzpyD0vZq/@SYR73txHBxP8SsxgxFZL0OzYR41qAcmfWGqm/D3AvH2p7XS50H7q2D7k0rxSwTCGIKZpefpbhqApTvdk3T/rFf1A06pQwJwqEUj8EQ7wW7wMvIClznuhzGcCfLRMKhjndAyKkAS@ZTuImtewiDmPHj138fmDBLZxhnbdV19nqDwJMbGBpyYk9jD5jDsUwg4YZhh59xorTlrzFtLyWdhchjUwk0ELpomE85vBsotGGP4jIfPIHzGw2eLTINsG7MWF8nQ6xKLg60eLVoGMRHMPIhzya39LkIIMkjfTOUgMOZ8ye8Sft0apQ7ozd@gHmtBw4A2MQaCGwml8aLZaLZszzjbaqWUATR2kQgBNQ6gGy2i6VkvdCP1rVNr7HhLXjYaMoVRyccbvbpDvzXwtoJlDCuIGganl4m2Jwcjf7cDFwj8AgMElMMgEEWD3UnCTFZDi9kUCA2nIS5ozBFr@Mi0SPryg3w/EJc46Tlho4BaEUDoHxYJ0IQQFvQc/tG0gDt86joQJ4gr0XeeRmgDLd6KAyWvdBXOa6pUSRGsJClAE8iO4mrtalGCcKiKxpWgSDEv/fqPor/x3uj3oV@sxp4aLB8wqkK0q@BOQxAh/O5CVGX1WqReAQNlS7cMF0aufS6f@qM1ZLOlBGoGzweL4J3hl@ATkcrvJnn90CFG0RYrYVOY12pQxHmNd0veLwKScoKHyTw/2TxoCH56zkAARmZlMsNPNosmm9VqnHGw2ZpkZxEkZ4TkjCfhsWdrkGz5yUB7OgiGF6yeFkinuBVSBHgqH0ZBDBqLDD8Hj@vgX6B9Rlw79fNc8BxqBX4bQhEb21m3tTL3RgTpCNO6AgAb4jUAPf791YpwleGpUvgW8ihOyoBH8Te/GXBeAQ2MWHCV2zBOhI2MdGAQ@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmhfGvwz/ienAM/ip1z0zyzHVZc9M@srfP4pnCykb6aAR6UPN5JAhoybz3PaNf0Zljhh@qnzogFTXOXNYYoWwDf7K1E@qdCyno4x03M@CX2XkvvJ4ngz0B1xTYXfHzkSfOLlchStNJjW7VflzncEc2A5@zCVixxxkvZ5jeHZ8ApXadQa26RlphiYmTwxf7TD8by0IUTnZdzqeIPgzmlyNRdC8XaGo227jd6Lb7QRuHkxWwi3RtJcQm2c8LqD@C65IemBPPtDDccLpfGF0J8nbYaJRfj/Zsdk9SRyO/UCcfd1lwMO6IP9D6BAkGOY5C82RDH6jKN2ZJOiLJkNn5AxA6pt6soCpr4A/WMBGhPTxmHBJMx1V2krk0wzUSxLdtJ70k37lvZOyr2gJPRmm15YBLBEjzdyrNEbKuiuya6/NjicL8nv2/vg@i@L77GZ8SQu/ijNXzWs88P2yziYWECDiAo3s7Whg0YFv9a6hs4RK6I1yFU/wzij2aL9YDzHdhai7fnS5D@0jHb558BYi/sk6@t9cgUHy/XetPh26PXs2B34zwn2QCfr@lhcsjiYg@kESec/17MKmff8d84K4@OnDByhCgBhLjMtGW8XQMcegdnvhdHEA@JY2j1u0rrV72rdV44ErcHJP0@xEW19F99s9w9LnRi/hx0xH4AYlPgKFjfjVuxUcGR0xPYfregkYu5JhKAzjSHQeqbKmyejp02RyfbPiUcyw9dBMOWF4sJ5@GH6NNeMUX43PVoMeEI/HcDr21MTpz/F8POfm8C3@FSafj/Lxh9ckWmq4nSBABz56qulFtsmb2OdRIizSO4wIYVx5uchorTqAiMaMrtfh@5Ho9pJC5UYS1YJaFpY/BLO6xs2bajzSKoI2yVeZ3q1J3tbo3rnNRZoaB7ZgYXvvN4Rcg4z7ObrdRBQi97mxxhz7Gk9AP5qns9eMKu0VDDVMSZxuYpK6TfJFUkDN@ACeOOH0CTwR4MCYtHmDCsqGc1r@9wwZhYz0cURq8X1ASAcoESpykvtoRGIJgRuin1@GeXbX5tm9lmd3Kc@wByxnGYkkdJey9GsBq@emKrCM/mQNd8Yg1J3hcRPbhst2dBdnK87jZrxipln8NF4Bhhw34pX9BDDleC9euU8OL155Ro6TeOUr4Fj0rfhFvBJ0C4zgwis57qK/z8LxvRuv7CWSl8JEPzG8IF85XgnrFOLs8FeiCJACyw1SIy6x2Y5fzIlrwMBGQmWaYYvx0qg@0TxMmn4Z@OefdqKPvmAgznFuUWSWYurSoBEZMXg@MGwEHxVY0ZMr/mi@f/iA9kOFUTCbFOh40TQEHsTwWHyZGXHEMJRWNOAJCCLfrKzGiEVGsndEx88dWihV8nL@RD2Z5IFegsIbELm1yIS@5@WnD@prGQSvwHfDExOvw/MaOkF2hBGuySZXoIVEfRm/oVBY18u4@LUfrSGa616OBNhKQRReSwQ2wtNBhqPFOcxs7IyXGwmF4q57M5qGJuV4p8TWeyUZcQW/Z64JJm@/ZMgYop0/eVNxIukQtSUWhIGNTIv3snBcIF6MQQteF5FUeecDFCI8B3q40T2hb6Xd950Uj7ObNI0V64ahIC3PkjjXMpuExDKavprqE557qLzuo0Gs91Nfg5QznGtJIIBIyjAXzl@d95DfHS6/BwJ1QIQrGawSrFcPpdfF6xtH2SuYW4tsr1cgBqbZ/eRK4SjMYUFy0A4ikvlNbe2aiI9bPriQzzMNoV@R9gOyhTrBLXS7qltwWCgluKfLnicaeJ5o6wl1XSKxTuVAaJExJx8OL3iI6aJoN@PKC76qijGE5rd1670r2F2u4GjlITwqgHuF5LyXu1Obdrks@jawbe6DLFWtMM7Iabk0rOaFJ7B7WroNl23B47B9dP/wyaOvwaBbLBaT/hg9X@CHvRbnWsNxnEOmzdXheLBCbdHS@EEjXOzG6Xhv6LiTjaYtXuMlnFmDMKBDLkHz8/t40udlEX5@pe9COh43QlEf1smiG@hLXAlFHR2HbNOn6wQI8v8Wd61LbSxJ@rf7KQoJGzW0btjG2ELYAoStGQweBPZxAJYbqQV9jm5HLUCyzYnZ/bEvsPt/H2FfZd5hfu1TzOaXWdUXITAeb8Q4wqi7qyorKysr65YXb5RZdDUQs7wleju8W7M5dE@j0XO7XqPB05cJyqpnMXSNuRG3/5Gey18EQ46HLHGnriyLnT2orT314U3lQB28qartw80/q497h@pDZfcAdv7vDjd2apuK/ld361VlJbQuEaMPG0qi65bX9BB4VS0XCk8UQ97sDyYidzKbtnyvu131pt/0cE21FrjdV@fykut5o3UpVaXt6ARnmD7HZOz6I@hbcBBB2sZicdNiS0HYAijKe0p72i72vN1@y2/7lNfC3nfge4ExLlMdn3qQ5K2xdXZkkYR4gaw6xHFAoYF1RcVdyo@7GwLjiv4VSIwcEmCwlVOacOG/H6bgQXX/bV3BZcTm3u5W7aC2t1tX23v79PruY233NdGzVj/Yr20cIokzvt3bqm3XNiv8QRAo5BR8Ofx6EYzuRCGH7EyV5m@4@c4NqPvDt@SpN1bw6splm8lALVz0IH18t@N/8VoLJesiwPIFdpp8VaAy85X91@9pzlfe77jhNFfBrH@QOgw4huV8Qa1xbTRY1mm8lfRwpWkvW7T5PqI7UQhj45XYx0OGnx1lgLMST8v3VGoTOio4@xZXEDyWDWiqaI5gA5RRWCkrDj@1sOCsMch1qq3Z6cNZp9QmSoT6BUVfGVWTksUU07oyAAp7h1oP50HFUviB@J4@LOtqR0PJoB6HHySDeiIfsBStQXdEPdU5LkZ7FxDPakU@/NodbPO1sHoWfthweRe7qnGSfuMudVUYvg@OMTocZExOeTgQKkds5iIB50cArk5HBoYnoR9JJspVIuu2Uc4UCZs2rhq02ptEVEYqcQP0hNz2KFCZsp1TB1AO8nq@hHc767g9UYGKVHeY99QqfBCV1/XyIQyLxhYkgz4zIEIyJvEIy23pVaF333JUcuNGja7WkeTQpEYF7XsIbNxA4J8BQ4CyiZ1Ok2cqNmMFmH5bs3Im6BNH4tz2j3h@YufWRdNLFNBaW5lf/S9fbE1kJ7FPMnqKjB110RdvSMtKvsps94c0xlmsciApSMHmeX8w8qUPM8kW8I0TT3OUGxMb1fbZEFfXBjpM19jr92KVnhIX31LrKTHlfWpljpe781B8RRGGifNpEha9O6DjnvYvvdjdmYNLpCsPxy@0EOa7chx@TkaMiaw/rUh2/KEQmHS1vL61cZz947OD6KQiFiQ4sFE6xH9iTNRFw4Pv@VhhcYh1lx5pJqpccHGK0loHT0tLjHIDjPaB5z7t6141SmGaqBvf/A4bm@nv/PHbt7KUykIy6YjSwXkmkm6OOjJVOlzmRGkVkJjsJGRJ1mfMF4dhhvL6Fexq0AtwqtODHMG@fSpmmxYhpnWnF22SLDp0ru7uEL6t1lmjIoo7DnuZeH/kP2U2ykvrdj5SKFExcmaMiHYM5KJtx9RSeL66AW7rbnAkv@8PbvVO7GR6@CFoW3dC@yHcsku3w5JpKQbr/mD/uAOsTG7/FFhqu3M7YJkkb0ILOT1kTmc@HWrT3l3j5xt9x2OPwGDuxQlKCDRW20WPr6iNb@yMFLDjYKIFUf1gq7q/r1KyP6GyJPewZWhpMQjYc@pdpG3r91jY5cJFU7hZDhdP5ktCo838u2swzyTeLaJCr0EcTY9QWITuJmlDNxapp2cWXkKw9j0LREO5JHZfjQwKjjTga9oDErJRp8UaaM1sZlomHz@IK4FrujmyNo7r8LOGtczdCEg7nMQBxXWC3DNYlszuvw@yPn5h6pEFFhwQocEtWknTfEP7hDpVPKCMuVyyB@/oFtOlULKXBXba0A6KX4XkCvvnGYoZSRbhshaOiXW9ONaoyfp43ixzWCER04ALTU@dKBrNlGBEPH9Zi3eoHU16meQURItMhCh9FecKKn5yracwpkY4T5bDBXl8rM0zNkcGyxOczmrYpdszPYQu9Mq0eJiuiqTtnVVl/3@qklkiUZOh@czGmESCvPL06ePvwZ5uhSme/VnYModMy89Rd0D7@whkMAn4eJ84t7brmPSIAe4gnajWmwEzVZCWOjPmlETbeTKK40e4yLkQIQPX8Yj6Ol2rrcZTuM2GLjNSHDpnudGG2BAOGyqj5gb1r@@uDgL5u/XN/Xh9MtiQCaqD19DKf9sfBl5klRfz7RL7BGvY5DdvOOxxNrFn6gJKhs2Y7jS2Y2s7UXiVViGR79viLWlr6yRRu3XMWQNXwseLOQR6xuleafp4L1ssxZu6XdupqkV2JdlOnEWmhik7Jnvm/N5dCLAM5nMJTB9sw/cweEH/CQfHgCQysTVfhmljfxc3pgitmo84epBWC9WytTjd@@2g6fbgEsRJPQxUynlEBfkUtrq3bc86WS@UEuUJuWDQy1ApJ5XNpbgofcOBLiAlQUhv4ntswoKlhtGUhHnNWR/6UbjY8sZyesaak26@uFpYeW5x63rOyOkePT9xFpvllKLJ1@11g4vhVeu3s/75ZVt11ODX03Fz8uV3pZ4@UY@pruVH4s@3uFLOswvVZ/R3VT0vMOdqBF@yb2IEHs5JRFalFlS0Dy/NKYlBwpvmF7CQmOJStdg1XAgTu1G5e7RyUu6VC6XuUe@kBCO/0VJ5tFRcyuDDI5pFScbIzfzR6ARzavzU1etdKnjN5Mif2jREsWkIfXnrDv3@TmX3deI0DgsAHIFpXW8@UJcgzw@gzQbbk1zPu8roYzJHgWMtLJCsB2wVVISpPJ8n4zim5RNm1CsOrWaDMf@d2NaDQu5iMOpzinGNCNZS3/xv1gNjxlTgEwXKcuQbB4qwLyA4UZ4MLobk60S0qLNFWa4VYTtpx0AcoSSLw9RxKgWbQiCqbbmOTqwg57nNcyCBqObfuJhaW@MY58RqQY5P8aDK4Q7ZYKJwgkdcgNDPgG8bUAWv3AM2@7Co@Xgv4kG@8BnViO1kWEHe4pUiUqD@rb6yfROXXyMCCOEfyJorp4849cqLFpJiO8iHC/B1ltz445oBZpXSKQ/QWMCW@soRcNYUZxqhWk0m@v7gCuQUWtE/3YJskd9uNCPMb0t2JgnfU@u3ALTkLuWkdfx0omKZWLGsKWYyx0jx4LvUwEkXbY/eejSsJmrT63QIaaHFg4gceGT7Xl3/Ulh/cIQ6T0LkJT17Iz2bSM9JuiAV5crRBB9lehHPlEp/jfJdq1SUzblRV1nx4iVHPd3M0ZIkylu6K2@QG/UbfpR5PexK4cowYS2RkI2lfJrR@5IylygTMniYfiTpmr@Xdc@HWCbyvkrWj19Ld5DHyrNa12SKS3M9v/PS0gGxdQrYLEXUVEqKc8hDZQZVWdtganFCKzic8/OwXS9HUJaKRuLwmEmtr71K5fQi42VmGg2xYrwxsGaMkRiVuM4lJtyYDRapHk6ei4FgmGA0ZUbuuik80YUnMbDINWeqFSvIGwOcmjY9xMuwi/yGP2awJ5Ez@dKzEx8I5mNpvFg3JwnEQncuNZtMSWkCcxH5qBt1xywS1T2ZhjhbSOzGToHDOj2xwW7jGHwulBNxQWEkxQ26hyma0lGGomHf27oQidfWP/KL1muX1tiDjjdWFWwzXLbCshIG7iMvGAXwDcUuboKLwaCDW0de8F2xCbV2K7L8FNctEcTYzJ6zatDskfwOnrRBOhXKqT1AvoKCSJQQXJydwZgMFrD9K4hWnLj4o5xV6U3kQIPGzONlMTP3FJxvsADu@GdxJKTnZPSA0sHAbXo5i9ZoAa1@LGlq29ehQvk8HXYj8D5GU9oLy/rLhd/8bfM17nOfFQuPizGSXerr4ELu8ZPIwIqIZBKW4TnwafGJZcXuhptyN5wFQEftYKJ/T7zpXXq9nmdVaMbgjAEtWgNveOm1cpa174WXwIALVsbNJOyw@xfDphzu0KLLJWaElXDgyHUYcRh@MT/LdXGT78ocC5dW0W0zdfWl3wIBjcVJu4/bYb6wgJsAoQcKdb0REWXRVkmU@O5Z48Jrly4Oooga8HMSu5sIydDrj/wm9QyfZFkdAiXXIFFlvdYUJlRfs@PCODg3CwGYx0QUMAiYq6S7cLD0pfkP4aB0w8wdu2t6Jk/Sr89jhYa7N/RJ@kYE5l7hYjHcqYMP3tTqqr63ffChsl9V9Pxuf@99bau6pTY@8h03LsrZEa96s7dD0iW8TZdb8z36kKrUqWSKE6zK7kdV/eXdfrVeV3v7qvb23U6NoBH4/cruQa1ad1Rtd3PncItv3wmC2t07UDu1t7UDynaw53CtppgVlVN72@ptdX/zDb1WNmo7tYOPXON27WAXleFWv6LeVfYPapuHO5V99e5w/91evarQMGurVt/cqdTeVrdyVD/Vqarvq7sHqv6msrMz1dC9D7vVfcVKArFWblQJy8oGbWFRE7dzq7Zf3TxAg6KnTSIeIbjjqPq76mYND9VfqtScyv5HRwOtV/9ySJkoUW1V3lZeU@OszHeoQv2yebhfhbckUKJ@uFE/qB0cHlTV6729LaZ1vbr/vrZZrZeUtbNXZ4Id1quOQmxDrppgELUonZ43Dus1pltt94DmjMN30HewqZM/EGEIywoV3WICQw0CrSUi7e1/BFTQgTvAUR/eVOn7PmjK1KqACtCo2DyIZ6MKiYgH8Waq3errndrr6u5mFcl7APOhVq/a1GG1OjLUoJDxkViHKj3kVqOfCC95JGa1DOc63J2qtq0qW@9rwFznJg6o1zS3MNk232ia5@CjN3aI4vdxZuB24wcr7ZufLj04p7x5IjP7jCb0mLS5t1WlGVm7tkpFCYc066xOuVKKp9FMEybSa8JlTcs7vThr@L12HzamYTE5@OgGZw6C99iIfHJs3RHDSp@vcIF0utF4X2nQRrfeaNjOfUom0PheCX0MflcuW7cRARGw88bBz4sXQve1BKHWH@mLTlbUwwUEcgr1H4nqm9v1bJXPtzxdDMb7AGyOjgK5NjnHVQqJRjZ2RMiWqEo@meB3X7MDF8wY8LlmA@ek0IzkTP2A/vS@RS8yOcQ@kHSW4658HptYRsP/4plqpBJ2icB/tEcCv81V5gLP@@0sU4hXhz1/7qzfb2Vs25ThvCPaB55l7O8UP/XOpopnp8szsnztrGMJBGbfzUuY8P5Zk0zpfskNuWUZ/GmM@Mc22IjPB5yaclV8WK0PLTOPpDg0khylXVvAvII7GWu@t5Vfah@wmyssPylNfX8TfpexBX1BOLGlCe@Iy53wz5sTyUADjH1xEEl87SEjn4@VMfomYeYryniOTFd@C5o/NFefezyvE0loIXvhduJ1YjYe@uM49iSHX@9X3m4cbm@T6AS2T1afPlspWaHbrV8c@f2IetjTLHsdG9A8Tus0ToqNkk1a@PBIiXn4jtifGTifR0Y4cDedxh/h5yHU20hqMkGQobkB4hf1oKKX8kCHlGIHHHOW4deZI1MzQCbRVBut6bpjXuK7tFZiHtDKLJ0J99oYfwA7HP5miIcN0gykWYx97xLn0u6C5V5q26iK8uaGHfcgSy5l@FjcuIU04KMu1p@FdS2/ad6O9WIgqowYr9ztXJKQmJvGQhm9ip6M7HfsZ0QfALP3MPryi@Y3evyoHdyxuzs3GFVGdSLjdlgS59TRYbRu9JGGfIJgGnCqZmpaUzjltzVSPPb0cXLoGCQ2GhgVRGqBjm8ScCn0IzJdJWvAvlqw1VfhVDjvAJyS5lj9Tpw7qzkaSsn4D9HvxiuFElihkxOh2lVYh2WyfAz9WBhyJsj0U/Rg@P9CmsyAv0Y7ToIeUSvmBPBelGSoQivavjJR/Ctz0RC73YioGf/0MQJzHe@Y87Bh@vZmLPY1RALdOxPz4SO7PWxnZhAATI6Djfj4DVXSzl3aOr1K2bo47kl6ze4go/RcYaaKG3CzKycOL7scc7eCF1vZctYUq3CHiqpXsnE75VFPW6aprbx6GKQEnG38f@QX@QAkHPDMpeeitTrNWQU9yowc0K6WYhNOK/SYRMvS61tv7RZVzEVmQvbrmy9DKAK9DnxutpMji/SVqOcmPS7yTKwO2Ase/Iljm4zJR7usO2VFzI4HOA9bfBiC4COjK0wQHYHOrvoiaCrzkBVFUEmkdRj5GYS4tXNEWp5Wr0Ls@WQSHBpif9gTR/aenGqZHDlx8KExjJvL59Rbd0Iod@7XbGGx/GK970B3EZXJsYQuj0ArzX5/SEtHF@0mHB1/YufUB33o4PWCi6H2X0jzmT/UJxJm0U/VYNkku3eeZsSHPKMW@CNYK7RyzB/cpK4HDVFxTzLOrqgMMa/h0XVz6OiPl4oqsxalrBFN2C0pE3FNrahv3ySXEFS7DPWYgn4Qbi5YZ5Prwb1DOPyu@sPfMPdjCdRrea3QM2kMJJ8FSifVeuzjsTmSpg/6AZ9oUFfgBCSkRFEO0kJFVZqjn2l20npNqcg7JnyXckt@vJ6QSY22FFUUMa6unZhvJUudCSota9egobPQ4vJTRmXWhuv61s0YewtNXlur1HEvFCkvZBFRfmiWjngSuRk@fcSTPuQvPwwweugL7rj1EhQIY82Ke9Wbco7xg07BB98btuJnorSSabkDHL/x1qffY140R4fa7V/THQXehHYAzbw/zjOMRuZP/fNeY7Pfcc/8vu/SPg1u4Mci8fA44Ud02NmwfxVwDCFOaMUytSbRs/iXETdseA/vJUsx11zByBtk4moKo@Gkci5uIvjkHEqAUVBR5u/BtI@0sMyTp1EhK2l/yvp4Rbt0a9nHxVmF5UYfALSAW5/SoBAb0hEbJsWMT0s3MpzelSGG46nKKte@RWMvgfFzIhFfwyQwNsjcUEuINwI7s1sxPmqNnRb7IBzC0ZK35SEUTpDhz46LOM0kRV5CU@CFKq4WYkXlFmUMP4R4mNxO7uVn/2LsCYGfQL/4eBa3zGIEFnFt420pkP2K9jJKuLB6oM8ymiUxSTH/zO/FzA85CMV4GmoyeXIbNVjzhxZF2s3eDa7EiMzQxgeh7jINEjmNiY1JZUEt2Oy3A0uQyihTuJ1hve/pz/LgxyWunJxBMG1qyJkY0reRqklUQiTcKfXaOMriU/n7I2Z5@b69NkXA8iyVs1hE5kzKrFzYAsWX@RXXWv0hCePUFPW0qsdCMOoPFu5JvVtlx0zPbLNo3bTt7yoCC7OVabJcbDFpyxM8TkrWND5TTJOkGGuaEQ9h@8rPIZtPE3FcbmC8lRuT79DhNppFelPhpBL2d0vGPibFS2j0mokmHFKMO5yUlsLvRw1qeON2CaJhyvaqwRKjAZHRmMhjDNQUmUIq3Z9CzH0a9yl6tIhyqLdFtIv3z61EnVaSMy5PTVLCySXoCcftMNokuTRoQ/kCbuJkhRsKqXDBOXYmfJVXzJ7CyTASBCBWxV42OoeSE9yos6b4iKMDtDMNaAsVIYnoaT2u4RA6/Q8Jxl759eGO1nhoTLLFk5JAGoeQaFfBue6CZOzN6fWoMWYoN0hBQ3wGKcIW3ZBN5/dv1c@2hfIRBCnNyVrTt@CgMbZaImzoTzypMcYaOKpKl0yMqORAaLBooLFAu5SzjifbVaz@/KFwPLQb9DCiDYR8zuBnSZeAO@@VQkhtFBm3Jshia3LLaLNVdl2KRAwl7yC/Hoqy1OWNKwHwBGMqXy4SBLg1ZexxKcCud@Kcl0BU9xEVLBcxLOkje0WN9DxnpIOoOsOTp7EchVk5nsdhZGcCoYXF7DwRIrRmmZ0lgkIT3UxcYjmezW5PlIMWxIb3heLUFbpXkjQMe04IyJGfC3YkUY6KyiloDubEJ0/tRGLI35z6vBBLLUynEn1CDI@yxenU1UIiNVHt8nKyaKIk0cOO15pIJFLYcYRDqfBz/9g0Je7yPNQJjW0yEqsMrZ@NyNy0y6R9W@7XQK2xUbZZYxh4cctws/1qSIiVhFP2ux2wqwW@MoDv9p9urdFMNZjoWAHsl84Yu2RkQ8gr1hSmejQLO13jaS90UGD2tP22en@wvZ1w@3o6MYpGXW/4tFAogIlP487vjW41jpL8fj6ZO9@@6HTyg6s/Dd@f5ln2ex6HBHhhdtAedQkNiiDXH55JZAjgQFmRO6sNWbHXv2i34yEYcEOJzqNuk5zaG4LiCcgPlV7eH/ABEIPUE@xnNBDt@6zC0XflykJTQzHXUFQaKsGXKXN7RuTBhzb0s8ObKgYGwWy0mWjessvrXzGDILIJdxa7L7a/RurJqTdep9N31AdEIYangAfX0wW2t@MFCpIFN4xs3XsRsD9aR3mXfidmV4wscV4HODMxmTgTxi88fOPve2fV8SCTOvqUommFmryEZi7BP7WjUmcpWzuLvwdY4UNC@165u@4g02Q6TWemqV6P4OiJMHpcdGbufRJZbD4T0zT7fm4QdTa6OXbWQE23eS1gfNlz93JLbskeEjd1PC62QcOCwNA4wefK/UrA1OxfJxYvR@32/aQihwGQjv0hiSiRUH5OIPIdAI9APfyInvCi/ecsDevtKYcissBBsI6bcgcFGihgWQ@b5d@vMpVKRc0PlpZUpbJBD9msqmxU1BY@bGyoLXrfwPuj8vLTpyWRuVv2V/q4YT5eqw2CwSecS83z4Ra9UloZdmPQ1kYXz@fL805pvlFeWy8F@aPKBsz66env//Yff//3/8xX9Mt/42WDX44@hZlyuVx@vvl1/tF1Ce9HWycL86dH84OThbMSuOwf7DW8Xxtl3Uh9NDc8tdIyC8S@sh6p2Wez9xldVJmYgF13@BtJlxcq3Qzyaf01kMhRLGPTTS/23YMd5Slt4U3QgemtPCGRJqATHMdT7zQ9KODRfEOUJFygByrl5W7FHNzDHUyYIbxVSWtPPLxmvfRg0xJ5UoAtLs1YWb8XeD2cgF/ymleaZ1ku/fqjhubf/Ke3wdlGf6wWjzNqsaAWHbWYSvFPceU5fbXn8z6scyUbbQdSKYdSoqsFqBmqwOeFHu8fONbOFLkta55D9gCScVPBmcUKzgl3f2wsIwHXgjPrAUJxKjki4UsmFEl/ne9dU7d8pRzXqYSpDS8UGnoXw5XFblTC/sUSyA1EESCquSsEedGnKnHTxxbJeMqbL7qvLY4mxIBB1v3X2zzu8YHmovme1nlO7KUQ5ojV5@Ur5saSGEMz2kiR@iME@EJFtpMFtiRcSC9YouUdayU3U6yw4@3TzCe6DhNvZHTTpdAfKsYEos0dJ9x8T9u1aEVuuV5RKT@8XolVlZrW/VZWrEj3ojPyB9pcgWvHgPoa1nYtIwk9yoAEjvjsf3FzhPFBgfEUNdUtEixrolp9NF1GQk@bplMH2zm5OYoRIf8pQ2P729TYtvNsJWLYQXiAkQpV@dqu3wm015UhE/vMHZ4iOqDb5oBqI7k34/M8RF@dwrjfDpHOMWRWOY/GMzUlPRi6Z13XUend/sHQndRo2qKVz6iZs6mFcMEEJDD4dNWzmmcQlhbpLmGKhE1hzSEEL@hMdHg06dtUaHOCLjVDQbtdwSBIsBNT0vuW6KspOkZc/QOdEEf5hvAObyO1iGXJC00jDSkVN5vhYXZj6FimhvjYCQdOyhJUw5FpeEEXusBE2@WLX5LkHfgI0HWntBWgNkVYeY76MTudeT03MTkNOpYx9M@XlMyLGM8cilK0kSwTJ7UYRbwDVrSO/JT0AiFzk3FnZD3IZB4cBzqcWzo@j7CT71AXP@8qPwxAxwHM2DJEHfZ8EZZTM1QUAyOnaqz5TxDaHfeM8JtcuROw4nE683Iubx99Ou6dLGaOe9@Ov9iMiRbJZpbNqrS@zDYSS48VmhnzTuLVaKUFxtXgcS@Z4binxIYlRgJCJJ85@pQ/@ZYnhI7TiEl/nBaCJLoMmOTvri8P8PkbaKaTWOTT1gN70Tadn3lZtBXNrfyLPpQPtvwSFmZTycf0tM8ZtgkU2@n@fiEmJ0F@dbnwZLn4hHZCZ944O/QuMN9mg4tTb0xLiQDbWZp6jr8kuCFBiOtx4Jbo45jaKWFNxPYk0EZKWoTqYc71WCFbUZmc8ATlJyqzu1SYuNhhHheXj9jwO4pYzuRlX1CiOhjjvgzmz6DfRT1uALk2bR0iHAktA9ER4SPULCCb4Cu3cahthssC2znl1CZ8tzIQ6t58OjZb9Pq9rF6s2bmFEhbRsJrprBZWC9Nj9MYQTYzQeb2YWphTxfWXz/72X3u/p0fp9eX8hyH9jtK/p1dW0/JID/T22LxdptfTa8i2cp2e5GkPTI/P/vY/VH79TwQHKZM1@rP@1MBamaTXs2Uu8i29vkIPxeVlqvd///pXasO87NgQi3W@4ShGrGQosun2mHcpXdXQStmWLkRihQ2zAEM0DGlvTi9QjBovrxb4mC6ttSouPe35yuij6CmeFbNGrCokJxlGn4JWRlKgjAqyAtKoULRVTHfDqG2AeSM01eeHuZWAdgCftTpHWGWouvEwgMrQvGyLqAMzUiPt5@VhvfAyFap3vEgZnZKSWUJia6dl7erj0v8B)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/q7yok)

The answer is based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247975/add-a-hidden-language-to-a-polyglot/248071#248071).

Invocation:

```bash
tex -ini -interaction batchmode poly.tex  # poly.tex -> poly.dvi
tex4ht poly.dvi                           # poly.dvi -> poly.html
cat poly.html
```

TeX code:

```tex
\font\f=cmr12\f352\end
```

[Try it on ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724JLViRbSSbmZeplLsgqWlJWm6Ftti0vLzSmLSbJNziwyNYtKMTY1iUvNSIJJQNQugNAA).
TIO has `tex`, but doesn't have `tex4ht`.

`\font` is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246934/function-and-usage-of-font-command/246936#246936).

Answer (score 1):

## 353. [fish](https://fishshell.com/), 15920 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxb t c u c 11   .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )echo 282;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';                                                              # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{














































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hatax@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"ullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!![ ]?42e>8053在ｕ92g=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD4o6Ph/SNSoLpIigRAgN@kSJVKpepSd1WpRqXq7mmSxQJJkEQLBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uPly5eZL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuypY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3V46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbUsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6TzaffLRlfhqhn2kA1Jjy5hdyV5V2Wem4fauptDYp8cPHlz1zbJPJMdmD66jpObY7nTiHEyuws@z3YFh60yTy7J2NbAAxJwYVilTyiwFQdgD04Va1P3aYl3dhlrBOttixmg8mTOJ17NuWWEdekz32NSb6hbFs6ejjuEGEb2J7k5Me8DOzMmQTYamF6aj2N5Y7xpSz7DMkTkxeswyIZHT96EAaLvHToz5meNC1fowHduaQ0Kja/ZNTBLgAQDxSkyGBocz0udQmfYEGgHTmQdoWEYALSnEIP59ozMdMGc6GU8nDHDrmZ7esQBoZ856Rl@fWpM060AYEJP8z4aG7TdaACcDiGOHY/XllFAzFm1b7/VYBtor4HFiMBOoRmhVWDYL/sxxgWoQK8DIB0btl5fRmEHdQJX3nQrLZzIQvh/6ILa65Tk@MsuoYaANfZLqDOE@dZ2Bq4@AGj2DaPrpwVPmdR0X3uCHcXm/uQlMV5@w7W0W339yP87qYbXIbkcIq6jGzqEKYkEgO9WtKbSQaE04UD9umFrAKotvxCssDmTRMiyXYznoniWm5YFIaqYMDujnWlaFX4FpJZZToafk42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiliA9fyTIN7JseyaonHHDhWn0frUmZFli2xQpEV86wI9zIra5Abgs4xtZyHXwF@AK0MqKjwy@Y4oEW7h3aKbW2P9fWRac196AS@y/IqKwJEwFcFyFoJIMAzm8VfFn6E1vIVhT0ZArWH@imAlyzzBLmOETIerEIFHsrWlkKcD1krz94bYvZAOiBavsSKkH0BKJEDFICyWgmyz2d4QbyhYVl@sqGHyQjbYgZ@gHkR6FAC6meAlhkkZhF@8A58TQMGpgG30oABaSr4a@DOYhYQrwBhBajKgk@voe6dQEY8H61HxAfODWBUpDYyKxWJBBCgtlgW6qzActAQstgQ8lkG@AMuxQIDflVSWSnHSkUG9CxnGNSNCnhhK1GBT6qAj4rAoP5VaAAq4KQCtVUAqmbzTIgQW81iOKTNQlogjZqDNDlwQ8WpBfxBOmgZKmSpQp6aVl40QsBNy0N581lqnVoBarcIYUA3DXDVoDlpgK1WgnBMWwIalrDxFuNpTggd6QC1gs0d2iEQIw/4EFyIC26tmOX0063xUO8YE7PLU3b6mLSA3aCAZISkGSwePHNITUAlA2CwFwD6GrSALJAjC1WbzWH2lwJ0YD4sR9kfcInPsOsjM0OGDczKIVa8aJMJO2A3SeCOy5wTWJkFbROGi66ObA07uUFMKoBjTmQGmcAYajinOOYTp1nKxiNu1HFxiIeho2e4LsO4IBd4aeJb3rTjGa@mODgt8OoDIzSAX/Z10woRoM6pT4irwjPuQX7zZbT7rjOiHjxCvmQ5znjNGABc8AwBPXTOjAXqCyapj8cWDEXgb/CREJA500lYIckmmitHCBJhuu7QBICUFbBw0zW6RHu/6JA6C8x@GcUK0@p3sgjlXmSMyrKxA/zbwzT21LIqMHgYXZatKz3jVEEfPo4tj1@IQzCywfjkg@joIGgg5oRFCOmOJtOYeRzUrOeMlovGmdZBWPShiaONdabPofb6wK@MmT4CcYihzGHDCDmCFsNrEGsCBD4s1gHrOXZ8EkI5c0EygEKHJSHpA2kyMUcGiI4OJMEazxHSyDIJs84cmjJRKyeTrMgxuUIoWbhKKO6Ri3jwzgJjaG/aRaph3qZNLQjGHg8FJ9fQe9xPmLis2dTh58IgOfbFYxkdGPEZohaR4mCENYD6vjjTJYg48Bu2BzKZJzMThVdo@QOnD43tzISyg7gESRewu0QEJEHoNZO7skAkxwY0OrGYybrjMQN/EEKgeT7IlGBcd7402WsItIYgl3WnrjtnszHUhDmCWJOu0@9D631tjIcAgo16rDvvQveESsbWI/Qc4kjd8XIxF2@bBsSxUdLbe/p1NjCA7CAF9FG0xya/KMB4TEUgUug2lxBsHSiFReiO50QWABOm6DuOjP49x/CosTjuSdj1MTPPGFDXgH7WXzCjEUo80EptktR6wHn87oXwMUNhZWEwK78VfGTY0HW60Cqh00P1YZ3usj5oKBG5AIU3vds1xhO/nTjEzkw7IkQdPkAhinwlH5jsDYXNu2z7SquBqGHLiQgIKFQi6mNfttOR1/pqEIgMtrGQ4zlnsebXsocYp1dyF19inCUMXoprcBhTl0CJkpjEdIKsBLmj2R0iL5wgtyEhBnqbO71efPCLZu@OmNQP80ZsVGA7gqyEXojHehgS/KzrgOSxhbDqSx4YdcnjFtC6N1oB2QmRtHpRX1nRZWCKtwEdObazAioQM4SLUZZDqC6oMT5DrqFbYWOk7uIt1REy7IVmjgMZjKHjseNCz@BMZ07qGVVZpHX5Wk0iHCuSoNUvD60wZMRxwJ/gKAgJxhboctTFsKeCuKoDpwAmxrUO4HkOzzGCMPV6guXjd0asnzcmGEtt20CJV3fnHAgUD4ZnyGjOTNcFNniKgwQfg4LBRKZ2CmMC6F/IWZEc1O@vZi5ji96bdszZVdWmi57yl55wqrusj1qNC0IHdKJEvO/Fk1Xyp5SRIFFxxhOFkvK7CBEpkgxVnuiDogSDxANgNM/mdjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmMf6@PJVey@BD9sNKMT6Nf0VmUDGL4lCe4S@hEmGKDIGKC7IGdAJwTRvVzudXR2AdwDVPTZHqVGIZOeqpwL8zLsXpiXTwjEJVpemWfhuV1ySJFRDUuA0ankNEgsEfAdKUEJRfBQFH9sRQ@S9ngYyTXcc2rTJAZLcFEkyc5DYR8GgAQhY4LwYXbNSdsXV@7cCQSXjVoNGhtIU8A2e8momhDM9sjAqSGyTNKIn4k8cZ5NsG8kklBejHzJsQGxCVpqrc7OJ0MXehy9XwoQCcgq2NiSA8L69fzEPJn2rla0jZ4YScReB0KT2Z2IVQEGf94bajdRNb5EVVAl4khVbLyYnkBfa7zkixUq@tFcw0Pxt@ajEqnhBGLgt9WVJOJJfb9Fg96bdy1fJOAu6OycG3UA/RN/diBkRGlfJgg67bWeyoFgd@Bw2NPd44c1vy/yQKVj2pUlD8vp6hZ5b2J0MUj76ODe0e7R19srYFhmp3LVQzFzpQIOtdOZNLCnSk7WKptRGAvA99s3w8aEy3FEwQ9mkjOLiErzLgwus4Cch0efXCUJSEJIDsoB3Pi7ItLwOCB0CR3dG14ZhNkglYIswyRBXCYdsABm6EDUMVwP8Hk6ff0aK@8qUmPfHzGzpjoHEHgqB3aQTsbAKwJYENTp8xGR0oIUato4S7twRWMG@HyEUvNVZEiUjjSZjw4f7B/VCKw/WSFRFMWbgCyluz0Z2rw17RnCqjjA/sDVZSl5gTjK04TrSgJ3u0sEXtQtWwMfAKCuIztMskZB0bwh4L53tWzkK3XDFkDvBOGqXBmVh7rvi2gEDxziuqjyrhpFKWAxWIVeK0esMHR52Orm80YxV44OW91Fnr0oUJpphXEgkBtdCDrxJPSRF1KkL1b76D97dA1xj4RIUAWkADPPYjLl5VkCai@SyeKesgcammMZ8mfE8UQmJhUlHky2yl2PlM9I/P2ZOUlkkvypJiEu5L67e6DdDyL784A0k0FKA@riODK5fVwc6XrQRmzHcgYO24I0XDoMMgSxaW0xdweOfa2GdPTEosZwfQX4L07c6GMYa8zXpDhSqqi6yldqdNs7Ay6tFrJIJKIQgVIovvylfqoDuRblfnbwxT4MImo@kwndGbqABJE0RC50dSO@5MEkyEj28VlZwHCt5VpvDwKkyGIHFtpndGHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv5KlD52rlH8S2d@pWmBD29a4IiQ7ODJ00cHT/Yf737enGj5/NJ7LlMuAOEgvw7IQvKQ0w176xbvmlgsBBeDvuFi9wIuMAUFJZiCn3ouMG4Zo8gcgTWthq9SJT52hnbcS14tzBmGSl/aXd6EHmPn41H9hKBo9yxURly@1IfjObaf4WQy9iqKAr18OO3IoLQqX3YdSx8olA4GBstSVFRdDg5xXsNblQKQ8eYGT8Ent0B0mNMMom6NHFBeaMEQWQNLcPA0a2WZgyHowriqaLhJOWzBVBqlBxoC6MpKWDZiwPQGtPWfQT2JvGl/oGol3q7VjJZTxCDaUveHuBt9A1SnBIxWQIrklVfWvNO8w@bApRHSVSAxJm/RJIfHcCywGAiSNGuKen5AHOIWOF@KvIJo9GqKs7nApZR8JldUC3kF1DJQ00BmlXDOTRrpk@5QmjgSwJOcPs0bRFph3@vqdl/e8h0BsiD3fQhFzTZeNJt2CwT05h3CDRfzGvNWQ20lq@x6ki0/frIKrXepeNh2Aw9ou@SEpklPtoaf9fTr7KynU@/qMWUyGvtjjjRmj3dBkHrtAL/uGdG@hwmUaKCytRRXwchvlBUTQhYmFfCGlFKgQ8FIC01PQbwkEHpRPISWA3wrkoAtZjN4OfjieISPoNKN7d504h7N/KNcg7Ol3hiISJPNXeTSHs4PTmB0DFs@cmmoXGTS7MyI4zy67vHZSkjkL5wG6UFXCyHQrHw4I22HS8LQCCgVqefAOaBd4bTpcDHLiEo/tDTIkHDCyQeQIGxaPRgAn4HEvCC7vCA8J/JZLtKJ7ZzZCK1jsJLUMSd8st@ZuriAaPaiZYPoWY3HAWhUuAhfp5XGjtHls6w8MZUClECdjYyRg1MJIF0RKzCoCDpfpURd0MMZa@hWGQmXYQC@xO7uARfrGny@SBqhEgVNap/FJ66yK32h6NJraM03yFZY@N3oMjtV@nFAgOU1Y5ol8WdASTpxRhTpM5pvwcB7gbgrjOeTIZQYWpio15yxYV/V@bhGmEhWaW03HgeGb9qJ8/jGxka8Eq/H0@DaAdc2unbQlQLXDrkkcmE8GV2UIk0uDG1QCvRrxS8bAeRZsoVtYIaSw2tznNAblUq2ldYbqv/U8JmEqgDKQ2wJHwAnnqzV0JlMivUzXLMB@T1S9j1sO8@6rjn2SfAxCAT83adBlogA6j1K865RRd30ZoqMai4ojQaKmAk33mxkmq3mebOXal7G05g6WdVroB8C85okRvLAdaZjENwauYoEvC3ZyFZa1U4tnolvJRIlyYKM9GTyw1IypXNaJ@IGtKlEsxkHkvrUaXSHLsGbpbVkMiQU4NE3QcuwrERcPi9B/p1kK5mKQ9pkPA1suRaPA126SASPCo0zArwRPTBnQEromDDERdcUiEHS4hR21y@M8XDuRiOEs24gZeMM@mIDAO6TQC4e5ZKvefqoQLek6QdyL48Hwi1O3qG8NJ5z7i5wTJvK0vaVYNw9lfojZ6Irn8qgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNiPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3eDgFZhns7UlDqzLHgtEdOiy@eRegs3C9B4cSXLqS@AJYAKDXleGHTBSlElwsAemCdmmYwBdpfwvNyqiEBGc9wdx8vjB@JYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMCkkAKgbak0IYmoc78XTEHNPN1bV3CD6UhDRVv0wCO@MBydKItZ9eR9aDxKJIe9HNIcmT0BAv4Rx/Yo8zrwjV6ypZAq7SOO4QRAkqDnFgLa2vkByiON@7JkxkkFRI44EYDuXYHQucZ62maVujm@5UgDFsFEHsIlYRaqQ0qbhAkqRCY9Ct5n08LBTr6k8P7@3zuhAZbHF5xHq09cnpTkCt9venIsAdptg/tybSdkQlkCNK/PrGOHGfCtXx4WTczw5VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O6rtNxLJoKuinpIv7U9XRL55NQQejup49B1n9@/KwmVyKRFP10dGPeOA@5OltOz4PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9gyh2zGDyhgwNTfMAd1FPgX0T/oUriG4vuX0H@Em@VAVvZnEeg19PQjlikibqDDXUS@57mauUT/tTpYGE@leFxwXGB7rmrkfzrp95e8s@R9IiFrshbeOfLmG@mWdMQoSnkeCXfVLcWJAipQnHBz3dV4PvMK9xoMDStYQTwCwQRXyWBst1B8At0EJXG@/80AQXqMiyHEoXGJjXVB1vSuTVtAnxpLPLYQ26B@AmOYgpKLsKkwf4q7Sj3FdvylSY9zTwdUe5o92a7zxWxUnVyutSl88n2zDSC269Vgs9K6aJhTPB5GI6iEG6SgYtL6/bWihrsxPJpTFyhJVfAU0BpmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrTPQf3AnWabd5SBUcUM19GrGoTEfVG1M2cSCHYYi89Pd4fATlhqtkxKqJ@p3XesnsQXw6BdMK5GYQX5exHCHXD@RkfDdIPNb7T7kCdFNhrZN3cN7pUqrV@PENlpFwKCXnLOLk7SpxesASPbqeyNLXPSYpfyxGkPkSSTqWtf3ZPHRU3X1eee4G9lqbHdo48@bWRaHIIw0nGBq8RrcRZs7QT5GOQh3GsLLtyQMzEnNODThgMTy6vKgNSM1kIAfYDBM6iyMCO/RIj6hXGxKEvfAIU0YSDm3nyUZkbyUu5b@mRi2LzN8VXG9eTmy0F@NjXKfsdfW6iwDC3AgABqYhigWGXPju/vHx3J0HK9RHwfF2oq0B317hDkkHWFDigZLXyFfdiLsw8xTRK1cwG6GigZbT89NOoqNHpQMyB3ZBEDw02AZxLXWLrgTctalJALYj6BcFtVd0I0CoEljCSUiYBVVuL/3OYalY9nBVp8iigJ5E7cqQBtzaQ8tc1XsgfjCYmnECXOdVIYFmqbCWJqm2qSWo9rjnCFGBQpkg2hBI0Gk14D04PIImu1qnypH@KinuUOkLqiSFVBO4BralD1NfAGyYUg@Mlrb9iLRkYqt1Kbq0DRHjJ/8y4vfwQuQlgG7Rkrs91MUH@/1pE5DnzJjzPy56Q1X9mhXmGb3CHyqWWKHuyLIqZD26iWt0Mtb7aCToashGZcsCABS4j5W6v9NkvhxPlBtcFk5JFIsvOQ6BqSnF1cEA3ZpsaIhuBSGa@My0DJBMb0yIHSPPK3VUeFAOqt/n4R7LNNQQy0qeUFWQzhkrpyekUIlU7FaDouBJr2iUPLOqGrnZHVPAp@YerRiXU9Zd/0hnRbihriwONq67DzRp0@3VZEoNUNf92cPGje3Bd5QVbUlSN60BT6ipyX94osZdsx@lN7QIuM6GbSq1tiSuUSRe53Oua6qEAE3P4VPFdEAyaF7VmTc7Ia7NPGGRcYj4BxcSVlUfSr24zYEt1hdJhAKv/5n7/RA/pfr50hDBQ4wRg62jB0Y01J/bWV5SfFF7qtrlg@Dz61TJ0IQ67bQHZ1F4qkW6FjNWhaa5ckGP5HuHLg1zi0TbyBcHhDM@OY84W/4Lk6k1VrZzawzO66uFe2XfGsaJUH9LceEYELQaZBiYh18UowZnylJaJJIxu7HalgbxSjxszrfTidTPkd5NNbK9Ec4@@mvunHzOT1jmqAhqh3TOOGKnf1k2nPkcYng1BOLayIuyg9LfVKIA74q75tdK4uPi@gaw5gnA2e66IthjbljB63tQrPnnpjqUPKdo@/UUcY3ZCDa/H7uiimf8ApdKynmmnR7R1bog8dGoq/6UHBLaVShGjmFTJbemeOMsjw/VtZuIEAOE6tm0plsmtWkMfj9elRYaT05fLq1DO5y@mxaipA4dtWJT5ZRgX2N7LeUqswXJkj3ZK0XsS5lpmv2n9wLWq4dElpjFNcuDldWXML6uOA1J1aurtw3dDEF3gEqwXrJp79YeOp2XVAHBgztSirWjB0RAYMYpnBDrhFRrhrmG6RXQ7mKjL2QC3EQVwKXatZgNOd4M7QNW3qHRga35GJ@14jjUR21lGq65zhb634MATVlN9Xj2ivV2L1DsxJsrqWDuP42uFgaQ4Q5xhvaahnpmfQbTVhT1YiOulaK/2Xu0AwuxedrbutWXum5XjsGd1vItDABSrw@@oGHaWlqdsSzXlH3TfwoGArw6JCdWvgWIXSQNHhtrbWp24f@b7/fFcOF3IoVb2FQwXij2Or/nMtXz9R3JPbKogOe7m4jTXivGGIXcWm/CWW9aUDxQDX51aX7EGmRCllhc/orckYV1bO9Hnw/DmGjnWkDYaO8ZzEaZDuMEG5BI6Jy0Xsnye33M259d6NKV0DW7ytEJHKPbEMGKzofq1KmZZR3zOFmsm8O4vqW1NjaqxUNA47Xxp49PgGJePdkcr4xdj0J@RxDQBPoISxXvua4TthjeM0vt3ITHTL7Bq3izLLTG0M0vcYVeen4HiKjuspBvZ0vFSrS9qZfXQzyYbjoEs7vSXsMOR9@VDpFklpST73DPrdqDFxDQ/3gdVymUzGF2AiCytLLzdpUtkw7Zcmvy9lTD6LnBdxcTHNjThX50Fkie40XMuCtHWKPUUulxXbtI3JHO/vyE07jmO9T00BU@2ZKIqBZEk7am@qsWvijn9WhC2mLjyc8Oj0101a8NHG1y2BPqg031Tp0ZWfd6pNCdc2R7jutPx68/RNZB3ptlzwzDbOCfE9ttZ6WdKfDVHlkly8sddxCdXpGJbOH7NC7iZ4ZTl7I7xlpuGvyeIaLl@5Xay4x64wpfEciGX2QEsZGiODXm@Q8vUemhfwH2sjzRz8rQueGUZXme0b3XURxibwBRvvS0vFEWFp4tigX01wOx/qKRZuGPV913HgYHFvJZEPRvrA4HYtbuKUiwkL3DTD1bqFc/XURYVvlOlCsoUhg/VNAjrViTH3gudKgI/nXajX6ej26bYrnb@Lc6Dv0NvX7VS9PsTaQ2doD40h3x4evq3rHNAeJ9wOyU2oA9aDIe5YG4@XdrJH6Wk5lvUu9ETWyBml4/RX4rSPZ1zxgNZ7wZ3rHQjwH7dO3ukTzjvQsbbXDI0pjEueM3HGhkRv66JaONHD7@t4aLAW/fPOIN2o5wNFgufPC/9W3XKgO5PxmB7tsTX16EZJJTqafJvc1Oc7UGjvo@MO5NfOqCP7nrK/PYWWwFezmI456Q7xbDhv2cbA6XSH5m1Idwx9YpsnSjDlw1/fSXdFyphMuo/esmUCed25jO2lFg1/ho@DdZXuzx7xYS103CCvrJqho9PX0lg/6Xp8NhRdrIITwpHeyM9oV@iUe@XV1JwsgEa2LIXTu3xZAh3rcPc3SayVrOgoxIIN@5sn1rZSEtJRIJeMDAg86rpsl7ezRbpYNstv6xCKlpIwimw/eR9y@1t8aHbQjMzbgv9S@1ram7RykLOH04F3nWHy6foeiGh4Wz9tQVuWI1PWMGbptv9YR2bNUvAsIzzbIHNNjRvXVPI3LqpQPNWSdMeERxseUHXTtXNoljn2@J1J/bVLcf6WJdDFr64XctrMVyvTfsX0jD5fAkHXbSLiyHFxwzHIIFIXV9JxBh2ZORe8OOOynQEwdclii8hB3HViy8rdQKurPxwzpc@fGAMdt1Q/Mie4J3NFq6Amu2oX0a2wvzbVPfNrUyjZusaGhhn4MqQbPcGPbyvgPdYHZvfhUkWESPoE9jd08sdS80ev63VxNjQ93NEUOm6YmMImxxsxtro26A0rYl6dtw9tUiw6ED/tuDL2qrl1ZzzHQ2Fzct00rW5OaJbVf65THdft9boRibPpaDz1/MdqHGjPVHQWenRC/t6ZCcClV8Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTriCF@YPiwrlOGv/CtJwB@6KUYSC0gRCGwvmKhnMPhuenuCHHtVe0RMr7HZc9caJDcnnBXkHdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBEwvDRw48iKA8wrt8930hSMerKfLodll/cQL5lvEdWt4zZ@p2DXSGZkWiaoGfq7EXbDLGgxsOmkU5i2ppXceC7gUOa2WX6Tr2dCK5U/vGUaFw46hQYbNSIdIMWOJr@4@fJ6OtgTZl3yaFGqD8TT1rvnCt3TBwpZGZNghi6/nocuxAl7jPzSEd0Y7gW9Lsos2mLrHr@84qfefpHAaQd1aYgPlPR/eNLi4b3pr3E@exYzswGo2BUY6ODH60f2mjx@qEmOwRHl4H@vRuzeYZgV0zCHFpQx8bHahfa@F6l7GIA76vT/Q1QxHNDZL@F7pubSum1THcL2nSL@Jep9IuI/TQmJFusb7B8D4oTbpdLhLjfNxSH1lasfHGjmPzO3HbDDzUxzdzFRgK6PbuC@Uy7rdfmhdYqZ8tF/XwlO8SMXrc9sS6srpGx7H4/YY9SbbJ9wTorml4yiM0ZUB@hRyTQPrybuQhxRt5yEI1Akn2VPdokX61qrEAqc7eYwvQUHe7Dq6E@Y4bdudE7A/cwqbDLfx840AHCD8DjqV3p76hxdvQskadEd3WKgyR2jwyOnj4p0NGOyb67Hpl8pkh32JBZEdXeM4/YFfYqQss8RS0keTtw9aSHrVMVXNMN@LUa5fLabOOZJtG97WOs2YO0WsxN70UDmVWnpBzzVx1pBvRLLKi04H2lT1peesaCDSWIU2GLuj8yuSm6e3AmsqK9ZDpyMBF5uVVmLWiq@MNqbDO6vX0kLm6huSb9ANeEpr34/KhtLtW8kTw8H9472MFBuF2IRdYGAHWdfsKPiA/dW3/8S4t8KnjTfrm7BDwxlMA69gJFisPSeDBewa6ttYVAmrPnlp89mEQ2Xc16pE6JpEFW0myiF1PDMmwTyWy9za7XiKHn@1SdtHy6cToSb65A1xpkB4Fx7zCaP5zxQJqlDfiZk9V4YSdFXL@9s9VxD0LOAPIW85EGnv0VMbe04NHh8fy2FNXjk@7QzwdcU2OW7KfoJUykSmpL3U3st7Jt6P1TG@i3HumSnuPDmSMsIbefEVDggeuzC091s57@mZFdUVfqwVhqDFZLSA@PH78KLU4ickSe0PXGRnJaPDes2dpPGny8bOVwdHUD6B39J3Z2uQH@6qaXNF8n9u0OriOe67IaR2kYwO0UWiMD7n5lVuFq64zNnrH87HxKQyeyMG9d8y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXEoo6KivLhVwysjMblG3DDZ/r6vPEHCO37NJD4Y@121FQcsgqbna19HDTiv9VKYZl/J0I75dIzVxvrRNTgp4xGKJL0b2/L2Kqqq6j8zO9D/XK8msraznCqvVhyzl9h6Vkw1depNBLmkCrksxb95EXpRGwbgVvOD3ve4Kzs3YbzE0AQu/Cyg5/Zthz3ZZoLesm8aICqXFT241RvjDeYUEq3OFzioaeV67xhVvqWaJLzuQtGR@7kSR7e/cObktw5NPy5lgfPXnOnuoe2hq5OWIUY@MdMF5IRl9KOG@Fhu7WLqf2XACl3QhvMF7dnyvsme72HHs@u30Rjo6a4tBONoRDWPhGkQzLnJmrxqoun9d6unqb0W1580McznxJDo7aoPEBvf32P1PVTIYsDOFTzfDXW2om6OAsgS59jmbrokHHByFr6KLcIoNHcqU2@siY4XYUPhu8SqlfOb4Vbhj7isn1w8lNYaUbwnI35HctDD1ZVs6oNwDM3xDG8nIY/MixzoaOvKe7hrdi//FKhG4qSPmGgpQj3Pl1KYOToLSw6LvXi/h4dMF/rGytx8bEzY2HTsfMrSzDbh9tSbLHaBP9eri/nUJ3aXvLwPGPfPD31fmdTY2VGT3WX68OIE5zsjIImKAxnNKRiOvBywukHZB5DXtgcjOK7J4z2ae3lUg@dXDH@sos75vj@9PxekSBJaIV/6tcfCniZ6AqO2ceu4cn4hbS@QqVH7fFrfZfJ8qycD4QjYg@PN4NGtXhM0WL5LjA4vOnS954ZnRy@Czi5xqz2TpdV5qtUx1XhixyfXKcW8p2u/7idAWx1h8zAikD2HD4XCv@cB738bPrnAC1tuFkZAUhH@v2YqJ0qcJ6zoQOGK4MfDqf0e7JlTU95JvXVoW5qxrYkj4P47BpQt6e0m6j3fx2e90s4rHxOS05gPTDJlwa4UB9s0rGLDcMMKQkq/snP215NLWjBrm9tG9ShZ9O5mdCPTmwmp5I2KlUMrn83Y/oAVc0W5vYRLONm3SYFeJeXLAN/wApBIjBkVT/yCxadwOF1sAzrwKBmNQ2IZtaTc2X2Q5@aKMC4mqSckQvsqEV5NVgm@f@adBKRb1kGzUmVkTmn8cNTeJys64AFw1SQpmYdKKyzQmEbAZnSRl9oYBdMFKBQeZW8xl4k5Xoqfqqf9oWUNo8f3rwdP/Z8e7x82eNTOvSP40bFMK2IbfgzP@H2Z4IZffJBkMrN/JMp8AtyI6@noCqsxeUi0HJrhSttlS0RaHEHUyzeW7bikIHkhXpEvCTRJ4bhWJLAS8OOygx1Y9/Fr3CzwbTEWeoIg5apDyhziossyrjsQ7DxKbth1/9KgyF4leDKvjdIMzYt8sLDXPgOD0/R89gt19Bjg92Dx49P9pnAYKLRnNm9ibDWjnPzTZzIwlQT32TdmjVWNxPEoe6qtXiD@JAmLgcZxU6Qk4mk6GdQ7SAOnj43E@9xRKbBB8oGA8rRfnP31Au4zJuNk5C3HiAVByyhSZPDWVjY4MdQyNh948OPt0/Yoj//n3yRhIhCHaM51f/7Mc9/tGBwIxM8MUkd0TMncx1CNEz7MHB7sXZc6Q5dd3x@u8mkZF/OuEdfl0g/DyKINDHJ6DdnpEFuCvWwZJksId/58k33hZkRE0oMFSO89poiM312KnpmXi@HHHoo1205caOW2HIFqDMdvGjUPjpKZ2@gAGoT@0Jtz3kWyqJQUuTQ5aTZpuELP9ehhiJGN/egMbeMWC4Z55twigyqbAvoSXi3HGF2x@QpHr8WpIAdIVcEo4VkYjXDKl5StNV3v7aP1EGVQbuCbi/47tnmXvw9iv@Wx/cv8rdLxRsaNcNry1wiSKExhL9EnBEQvoj7SPfwrK5zYcF4dA@XMBXmTmCajolqmN0ngO/S8COF3ASjU@h0qC5QY35th54fobbSqC1xoqiYJNCEVSmnfbGjG97u2K1sZAv5FQFkJROA4BkZn2A53k5wGSyAt1EODXHtZcg32xvbzMR9VCjVqjymlU27RdZ8WWI6CbEFc6GiFyDQRpIskgBYXU/GQw@KTWJSZF7xdU4Mq6eA6MShePohe@2TwiRJYBYnEYG2u2e4WfTJu48sD7awQ@NRT7BsekDklQYk8iVFAXfSsITZwLNBzrp4iM73EoCbvvkIyCa9fP4RwPJ6Ce2R/l6z1oc7g2@9eH3NRl5AAeVzVwdTKN1K36GIJ4hiIq4qvk2XrDmpGm3FN42GTTTH65ozDa4f1kZrGmzvNy7100@Jq4abERisbvPbAcV7gdQGJbQFC2rqIXkoki53Moi@SXys4HioMGZC8gO2BSwjK5hfumMvd29/YOPD58@u2bWkGLGr0YDvl/fTjUlOd1ohY54tFjLVXLvgfLs8b0HQUUskC5EuDEwfr8k6k0lWcyjIcjFuYyrRVuF4dXSrcf4M35y@yq@We0m1CjRNTzUzHvkS3ujpQd0wulq5lppFbXy@ZtQWsBTIqD3@PHUa6gmkueXjdZ2vWnH4tdbwoqO8CImb2EnAFfT29pUsLFfLxwWLPyc5zF@68uL9sXs6r4obmbRuhaejp84Jwu7Yr5HJCBS3iAbYJGCrARR1/a@Qy6jL6zfafxzo9wOV9TKUAThQuYmikdAHQdfLkUusrDd6ZutHILGZpkdIbDuxM1XBlb2QsuV3DJTIin4X4DgGSf8b5nOKjOZNkIlksjtCFaa3WQJM4CXFKBDo3T3dAoazlNnzC2C04L3fSNwHTnAfkGPJ03ZYB9PRxCvT48jgxYfgHNLkBgoGQ9R5bIUcAnfEOYshaZGIb8GmsP0Cy6PevnELCkPjVnPHABvTyTTwNE@VNUWC41lYqHJOKYdF6nOFrVwY1f8CA8dR8n@XhZTZwsE9IYugyZuzBLxs3iy0oL80T9@9tlpPCmuaktkudU3Zdq7asI1RL@o3sxJ9InfOwP7qKu4Rbl8nUuA31XA3MZY8DmiclkeegJ9Xq6GkvuzifsInCBGJPojfcwSU5vbZ5MZvSaaCTtNhqukOjfxaLNUihQqeFCAzChln1x8/E7o9pwllBo0AvT17B4@Xptj1lBluQVuyiTJNvEzYXsgcaFhwqQAOjAkqRDYGjYhUDMAI95JZN7AIQ2GQ1x4kJW7FcH01SSao3WQJlRqVr/DIp99W5YcxXK54lfoMlcsM2h919mhrADYa3wukOuBur7pFqAZqL@yEFsw8uscL0b5xjgiD32bL4BOLGKWNTAFwwDWwmhqd@jiL7FvQ18B@aBSeX78oF1KKiILbccMXLOHawjcsnio4vnfgoFuqixFjVe5RvcRJkMrfW1unAaNxT2gDiNeYamxKBmufqF50TZV9cZW7yf0awFi5nAA8M/YtQNwaI4ymP1ZEbaa2f/sZ/gNaDGxqaonbfc0Fc9nqnBTq3mWZx9uNiVps5Gp3d3UQYuavJo1QSdXtnL3T41hv3MwUJqiyLIspyhb5@fxB1tPzRda4dXsMquWXp2M1UJDfjVriaVa@qTFnj79/E37TVKcnc5fic2ERt8o3ju8ENUcKvqxSpmd7xSysZMyfuqT6Xr@hM1Ab2Un7DVcJ32G/@R@3Yu4dXR3@q/pE0lxkcWaTfy2s1gUFaURb8E/qfsv4eKKf6Mu1@Wd1ps3yYauT2ZzZprm2Ov14OcMQYLUks8Y5HsHOD3FV1iTnqRA0TWa9RfzCHoebnUND1zKd9voQwYfZ7vGYDDd1@fm9MHk8RefBddzvF4frZiQaKVSCUlqXPWutPV8jGkZ7c9@snGZPn/a3v6zb44UYwMfh/j4zuVjdD9T8x9ubHx4714ul9Y0jbuffvH067u7u7n76fzTRn4nJ2U2tv/0TzY2NG1bUzZanqe24o2Tk89FLZMT5T/7Ubz99OnXPK@e/T@/8aau4q0It1NWBD4BV5ap4MR7CX4qyljvesVex6CVq7E5/bVjgf/5BlPrO8X/8r3DV7FJrK4pn7nwnMRexQqlGHeCA96ywdtprB7bxmiFy9hcqdVq4Cz@l38L6esfAxwMmW/DrZ4PYBXmsbpUoyQXsXoBHKqmQb7/9ze@EcGQs4kaiXHBdZc14BJzRU3cacG1Rde2gDb5pIyiBPHsyXBiOEwt3VHv4IsJL/CwDbRhbkyaMfxwLju8y9hRI5VKteS2BJf8AueIFFXVmqp6B7iB9OFWrSZtMW50MJvN30H7yEma0Ro4MGAad9hn/xBXbJVn9ecGdyTECht3X96v16FQ2Xp2q56iy@9J1KmKJdFx7ooszV7GQQVptF4@4j2H1cVMSRPT6TTvTjMklTRbtCS8@D0WC32wy7KrfktJIIrvG3v/eLF9vP78f/vz7//59@jv@/T7D2i00O6ZfWULIp1Cl6jDdbdS6dbrYt0Vz5v4Xod2lKmUKiWlfdlMbAEHah0xNfPRRTyfjT9jyP5hAGDNJKWGi7Kt@9njez228K5zn3rUzw/gkcmD@aUgxxLVyB1S7Vo8GFr97Z1S47TeklAgqkkNtZBvSTxVgGW9zBp3oZpErVgWW3Utrx1C1akir7jhpsecGGiGhYCOPr71RdnqYcjirR71itWDZPVFnPeNF6BbF2KNhtIyaEAI/NjdjcpGqVKoaEo79Lx@sep1L8Mwnnqx01h4cerEFgSNhU3zql9QFeELC1owe594IBlFONgsvCLOq1d7duNF8/twbcAf/cMVvuJ9g3x8b4py/dpgFXVLyyr5Dwv7Gnu/S4BxgnU7nc7rbgfFAL2jd3V1ok/1mT7XJ51pZ9ZhIESxKfyw2zBZimXz6mbsDltbJCH2prHBjjgXarFUcDVTt17PZbntO8nh4E@SnFlMiP0DXHVVU9kWjE8ZuIFQRk7QmfFPVQUWO4er9War8WYLOmg9tU3csVWXfCzhIbfvtlLS5WUD3NWq/79dD51VurgLCte6TKW2X9RB9HhRb6QA5AsfpCwxAiq3661tCgkz83Pzg7dbILxIqe3Gds3Zox8kgUuK55x4wbnbAsDbS8jevZuSwXUXANQ3oT8mU6lNSdrAsbHhjxUQuVVPBaVCHBIgLZyf/5w/UPSgy15uX9YvG9uXl9vb8L9N90v/Cb6X29f@6bG41sRZhLeQtTQbSr2pNH1G0YJ3Wamjj6w0wVGHJ8RrZLVSq4EOuOTWf5v/cnpxD30Q5ZYMWAuxLbYVQxN62diWEHv59qv/BX/Nt1/9PsqLDP6MihA7x26tbKG2WeZKJ9yY/dhmj/llgxt/wSv6oMfjOnra/GbjgpSivJRZhc/5J9RSISnjANx2@m08lS@zlxAVBTcYl5iolQpiO6XONRbbFgtFGpl@8doVj8f/0UutXIzz6Rk8TP7S87zHEdwW2EHkqpZRJfWizu2l8y9Y/OKq6x/94rpLiF2UmVEBqnQ9xukhxKD5xCQJRqn69gg3G@P6iISq6Gntc@n5roRzJ/qEVr@6fF6gdrBfK5frfGln8yl1la37W3BX4X9/A0rBmn2I2@zXuiOQepv9bF5rom3tmNR5hX@PXuMfO@7i39Er/GPHr/HvaIJ/7HEH/45f4d9uB/@OR/h37xX@PX6Nf88H@Nf8hWxWrYqb50SYlFpWLzdnIhGoGtupN39h4s4rlmE3zF7L/zpMNldmyVjzF4wZfiO8wj378Z9@95vfjNdqcSlO39zIqY7L1GQVaA8l8uLVu3EhVmOb6qaasTLdjNpRO@AwWcZlmWFmqPZAOWmrLGOwzDwzZ5mRo/bAZcBfBlxmps8yA5axMzZEhFBwTdqZCbr68BjAXx8AufBn4t65jprpMsjIQkGNPteH4MF10W4KDRZn4ksD9EtZlTNywWzhR04a4suXTWWrpZVLTMYmJbcbL5vxFprD1so51pkbG82XbRbzQEOtxpRmU@E0geISyS4v2@39J/fbbQXHmeZj53Dxf3g4ir7e@D86dB4fOiMH/g8PD6FvGPXU3RRw4Lt3a8CR/cdOrF7daVaIrwe8PaZs7zTrWQndhRSwaw39Uu95LSDCs77RFOJnCVQuzlC/qH52Vj2tkvsseAVHu7qIEETjDv8J1xmMYYG@cQbX6Rk66A2dZ581Qxd3KJ@dgddnDDSr8B80uOjrf4V/87@t/8fPWZIlGq1k4vxyO0FXEv@SyfPL80v/Xk8mEv5LYhv@0APeMcn5ZR2dFOkcXI1EspW8vOR@cE8ktznAOmSzXae0i3jA92NhlpQtvyX@6z4ha/9qxqsMOA5pz/kM9aOYWGX6YuNMsznLZJLVTmDZH5eB9QvanZCs0tfbNjsNtfWnP6KvN@wkKVI@V62qW4y/aDmtWs0Fb8VStVoKXjYTifL1q57ZUQugYORyyWS1Ci87AdgMvIZgSwA2eMkDVMPTuz7zPD84pO8aAOfIx/CDIpxTJDL0VRT8wFZcrIh37iT8D3fv7Cbv3NHKmYuL0Gc8Bi91yavd7pluu43@2YsLsS3SPpZyHt4zpYsLNVNOqfGk4yae4JfZIKuEpLIPtTrlWgaWrOWKEOwjkN/eLuTq9UIOfAqleBLXxBuIfgvwjYvxqhg7pzKopSJncGIVvdnf64ox6N44KLDzyxjVMcvlkwngrkmQ@y5j@Me91XKZ@ydZrpAopcr@X20D1G6QYvgfimLZVG6ruHUXhFr8W61TIE@unhs19bJ2blRw2vyy2vU/govGA4w7d7JloGEpU20K7fb93ePddrsmiiJKQnBDT@LuAtpUcOMNIk2@3OIkq1TvUjtQS3kGFc7jSHEYIVgJakXRtvJqCakomH20DQLlF1QiyAbbEDR64k0oczJtgCfoK5B5Dy7WYx02wIsNcPaTmcyii1mMh9O92w0jOfzyQ8NXSotX6GOEl@D3wixvwzBiP320u7d/nNa2JRbTHuzupbVnz@/FVHzNL94pOIvvR/u79w@fQ4Knj/Z3n@1/dPDp/vOn4O@xs8UVMH3/vnhGXSvez9hnwpfua90wdGNqGO2z6fTsFfvSNNsmVKY1hUI5A5d5RhvKMtYX5arCr2t6@pdf6u6YLvb2h99@@8P/7u3vfPft73z77e98/6dfff/b8Psx/L7Ln9/9N@U83n/61T/73be//Tvg@R/g90fw@8lPv/qNb/Afvf8x/P5TxO@P/V8kHv8JAOtXfvrV9370069@9Qfw@5f@7wfXf7/2k9W/739r/Q/Tfe93b47z3X8Lv9/jsIK43/1t7ofPa/F/m8f71R@8/Rf/jv//qf@Hzt95@y/@GG/@yz/9wZ/@p7ff/PeaVvrTf/32W997@61vvv3Wd95@6x9rb3/jX6uZ6O13337/D/7qD3/vr/7wf6T/H9P9997l/@0P/ulf/K9/8b//xR/6v5/A79@B6yd/8e@hq/ztH/wQ/7/3B3/7Rz/E///5X/3tH/z63/7K/0SO3@SO/@df/ht@/@tf@49/81vf@auffONvfv0nf/Obf/BX/8ev/l@/8R//@r///b/@J99Ez9/8yV/90a/85Te//Zff@ud/@c2v1ty/feP9q3fw/@ofwOfd8XwXOO9Srvf1@ernwufvQ41FLtBOoHX/8tvf@CVo4P@Csbff/jEeu4Hfmv8fayrF@TF/@/@AQ7teZgzJgAt@v/72299FEv0PQCL4D@n1nfBlKYS/fGfxAmT9rRWJfvmnX/3zH9FbzKjUaVkGx@6SVkptgX6zVS7747e/YgNJfmkZWgjAz@k7yKGWwr6DvO3tD7/x9kf/@O0Pf/PtD38FB28pV07vpiX1FrkEIubfIR5GLLxLPIz4Oeafojk0KfU5vLHP/cDPP/9caF8oeL7r7gX4fk5e/GI8CM9/@UFBGPrjgTB2waJu35nxnZu@b5gzY42XL1u4oAp@mHuKZI@tQDTKZ9ksFUxJs1kwNY2RZlt8lhrv5IvBMwFvi/@Fcyaw1GIyG79HF07pUk48mp8Fdwp5yCY1m0XmxEnuIQy5Dy0EU765MsMSzGapGSjB4IAcUhB0L8VqtVoKE9Y4PvDKUauXGKGSStWg3Jiap0m3Swhido@gQMpa6oi1t2oznjCF8OoBOVICeh2JqiamSrX7kGFtdp8hLAROYF@@rNVLtVkdwb3h9EjNUvcIJwRWS83qb@C9RjAhnRC7/wZQKdVSqXoJM8RC8upJt3kl5alwVPYUS/l1AE/cz79zl7EPRbUktrnAiATjsfGeWsTGiBAdwpupLb849B846bdFBN@grPxcGA/fIdl0h4urGAHgSpIsywx@uMK@w@5C8IyDSlG28EhxCClqEdQCQg@Gk0EpIUX1m6IXyD9W23rvC4FhYTY3N4VYXcyKhzKRTlGYe1Khww243w@VrwoTC2URvQ066RHgAumrlP9mHFfO4owDZh@m@O/u3S32IRSTngs/gUmprJNzYhzKdiolagC/7qSEF6CWCNBOCdCFIM9qtFKXEtJpxuRaDMPY4eGhjwR5vKgJKWjmWlbFd1wvmk6nMUghy2k5nfafMj3JQ/YdMoX6T3kTiUvfNmaalquC9lRl6MWiqo4KKjB6vnnzBmqFNlBVDkA7Zf5eKi1XokDw4GYuLGsenAjScmWBa@ZMLeQYS9BsKlxJlhRYgm0lBb7tniMRXIm4VirFKR5QX05sBVvrCio1B5xJjdUR0eDiM4ulfDII3Dtke4ePH@8/OR63Wkww6FvNRnvsOl3D8xIYtvvkPj9yoZULyVijgaCPKxoyGGG/kiFmfHD/6OBZhfFC@1WQIMSqtHDqF7OsCrHx@LPtmL@1SMTvkDniM7xXFmVLaOUsJI3VhVjXQM0CV8SrtKWkKjz2BvecGSj9aVFMqwXU7JI0f8yErztThlYyuUkN6FN4EEPe3iYKCPVzidYm0Am1VRDqdX9THlOF@rP9Y0hwfMhULSML9c/ZTMYMpUuhbtUswx5Mhpu4u01sZsRImTYbmTT@adks3NVcIa3mi62NDetcwjybVG3nuE3xEl7PJSzGB3Ax4QOBfQBecEEeuPeQ@Rs/Dw6r/u47tEeV4FvwRDUP3Swp4KQ1ByeMFxcgCq17eaVHiG188cWE1eugX0sHD4QYcIshCzagSWZPHspUzb2pa1DogLGe@amJH5iTe6Y3tvQ5dB2gRuzy8rIPkA4eMK2u0StP0cP7ZZd8OuC@nOlCzK5Uam/UXFHQTiqVN1lNE8BD2FJwh9sGNADaKLCl8L@qB5lksyUFOJUqivDIZrMCThQLQsUQGO0GeZOp1STeBrM5lTaDCPjNAn1W08LLjzv7cBE3m@FxMQQC2GDiskwQVuRh/ltBoDcgGm5/oy/kVv3OmblzJ4uTGNlcJpytoBKzS6ibzWwuixQX/v8retEKzva4ns2o28oYnDo4c9uKDs4OOPPbSgecJjjL24oJzmk9q2a2lWldYMI2N0zJ0O5FTZwYM7SDy/3EumdYfRnPENVEykATt31Dz/UgYb1X6zld@ph1tSeb@FFxPK7KE@RyYtWx0WRaDY0n0AFflkieC4PaGR2qFYzaQEYrHK6tW0JP7ji9uexN5haexrEctxYHqTAeBCygGyCO4BTYTjabqzRYSx474x1ByxdTDTUD4wj@1FJaS28YO8VipSd3LUN3d/KVfCndw4M@/rLWTj5TGcifP370cDIZHxl0@mcnV4YEaLcKLczslCr5fKvREMVUg7Jp4Td6OZeSNjagaxt6T4InLnp5klZqQeKe6dZq8fhOVtUktZLNlC6FBeGQ5ljCuoBJU1iyNNL93GcEFduxgedU0nraPCcqVPr9/uXWeWrxIujnEn8D@lxKerpzHr5WpUi8CpumJXMRCD56H8h97q/nVUQtXxKrjerivVgQq61L4e7I6Jk6HvppZs6vpyoAb@ZQY5BRkwmXFddxJpWO0XdcYxExqxaCiByh6xFy4mWYXTODOZ5fz64QiTQ7vw4llxcvw1QBWsLlJdCdExv6BTc6Wqe9sQ21nGvtAyNqtLYDc6RYN7EXL3S9XodKPs8VtVw@l9eyhUK@qMGAU84V8iXoZplCJq9pACBXLpWLl9CihZiuS/VaVssKmiZpWSmrSmoW/29xaPj/7vE1@NfwDqmymnCMNj2ewEgGo6/NHqFtgInDjh38OsyA3TO6a2LsDXXaRbznOp7394hzT7dPeNB9kxvSDIMe6viJLG9kToZrYjwfj9AciOH@g0HYH3UAQWRNPMI9uLmW46yKUGTPn64p5ePQdDUQg9uuhuhHBx89PI48j/d39x4KBXbv8Mn9K4@8HynPHu0/OA5fizw0SJoPQXx9/9Gjq6/@I3f4/Kg/dVz8CQ8On@cWt9ALD6kKObiWI4XeBMS/4SvJejDIg26ULwYOVcCjDXdAX73jO/OFhTODzs/4CVzTC7fa88PYFeE4OJarM@R6HYN1udUXVKDJIpsvXqvFsiCMme2csWKG9RzL0vF73/0N8BzqeMTQQBnTos/VY9Znjmv1zsyesSE8xtOMZRW/rYxICA8ByGjaJfNHIF@gfc8efokbl5I61tRg0zFb6wkP9EKnaw6GMB6eOUEEoaPrDH7ve0F6I3pNbvaY8DzI71qIdT26EBNEcU8UH@oTfXY3VmpUvda4nqlU7txRn7piOSvCAKl7A2N/Bu2WPYd@pLvzdEmcyOIDJrdjA1xvsApqzhnX9TroBw2QpmEw3clpRr2UyWf/@rd@/Hd/8utlbVBTt5qZvcz2zuNH@QowSZAwGQmRvqApk8qhlUv5UjmrldKlcimXVwv5fFrV0qCtFcsgsGfUkloo5ctqupQrg2iQK0Novlz0xVQlkEuVrQqAtbv40d9t0lrkIagnfA2RvU7oSRbTw/cpEw1IIwqoIE7o3PaWWYNRjakZli0ygKizLos9eLCXefBAFO/hC@6n2MuIYg9f8qVMpnhPFA0K2SuhmCM6PE0JzaeJE/6SydwDck85ALQ8LopDfNkv4FSXKJr4srf74AHm08cXDdNDtBMewl@s4KUI0Wx8AemZALwKoUG0XZ5PjhDdxxfMEkMe8JA9CBPFjwJ0MOSIR@MAHgYl3d0VxQP@sruLIXtU7DxH9BN82aVLFF14gT4gigNwDFzofaLYASf2BFHsgqs718EPP7CMxqntiS6Kc04eJJAozii23j0RxXbgj9l86mOTR@pW6EXlpb5LL2X8E0UtQBqjZcOXrCjmwpcclO3hw0/14aRnDPg1d/mzCyV9@DCrm7Pp/oPORx91BoOOO9/d/@gIg/b2HoKIMJ@6nUHHT9hpw@VAqr2Hmn4yml@9oNQH7XZFt1YGfdJu53T7SlB73jYQQ0j1CjDzrwFmNGrvQdDew/ZdfdUSLwFsIxMYwbOD170RPO/pHR4UXBREz1mnI1ax@StKMyGgEI@Ls9gdT4Cp2umR3nWdKr7PaiyTRpV/3ihkWlUKYCMQxjPVSwzvJ/Cu47xM8nzemNUyrdqsVtT4HqF@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pV0HSE04@zuKTusIR6Z@s1SzxJ7mggmIvNnR1JbKitHU0tVQrFF1tTUUxW8L6TLVYgYiaeYQxvyUaxtVPMR5IUiyld0SrFYrJ6CUSZwNDewfmSdiJxZugnySSii9o7FIHKyuZUTrPaT8zSsxrHi82T1VlNrXKjrCxzDVYPLYBPuxPH5RAHAG62k6ng6nhCVMslEfJXlEQyGTI90KWFxf7Lz752fHJ8/DmEMaHuzys85Z8sr/qvHz3ckw8Ogze03S0/QHXIceU95FpLIdy0dOB1DIqB/BBGU1CyAj88ouc6lrxPW9hApwoCAoussm9HUz5@uATn2dA54zmjhYMqGWOzuwZD0@Zmj@m1Orj0HksQVkxPntE43q7Xa@3aiIwAQBGDVJ8wsvu9AHPgcdxDuwuU/ByPrfkB7VrmstqpzWIzgNOuMUl9OXJ6L7VUt9pDi@b3avcwcbUNz07VqBmu67hiTKz2d@waY1Pb0/vGU8NFiyIHh5sgVeBZtkSfGclN1tzH2HuoPlxKdZfZC8yeTEcJkM87yWWvyCuSJvG1oMjndLgSd09cVvs1lniRrL6CV3eTJXryveROrtpL3GPtJPhkXvZf9pnGCrkqfWo4gZCgGxFtsMx6slb/BAQhDvikUgFE/Do@AZiYE4A1exSgJ8fmZbVbs1hCYjOWJPLkqoNaA1Nf4G1bEsWWJDUuWkJdkj4T6tBTq/OYXvOmHfoMBst0VC1TqM7ATy3mqkOoWP3FrOrWxlPXqFrw6k@y8TOkehXICVQDMK8vEm9/6RvJbSlf435VAnVhgezRltu1WdVGw3rQJGrZGgSkGrlMGlRquBXTMNprhbRaSGfTubRURF8Y6tP5NHiCmgOyRcJKiIyJ6cwsI6tp1VDTicxLs/cymT5JgNxCJGPJ9MTZt6cjBj5QSdgq6RWeOkumtC2LQS04TN@WqJkCr6hiwYDmQzY200MEdWToFqVIJiWW3UpYmwmMs3k8He83WpXK/mz8NQhKSK92CqliJvU6mawmNpI1z3gl1KtCHfkKlXq8AW3Wn39k3nTUgDoGl1rUKo1GB4tYzKSzmSyUzmxfDLbFuthKZzYKKlTRJSOGwTjHiE7Joayz8Bu3Ufy2DKg6taxVBZnmx7IlTSor@a18hs/R8ZTC2GdsSEmWaIrBeelEPF7U4vFkvIqrAxuiPx0M3Iw4WRzYavyOuiOCGCZWxLKGERZMkY7EZgLsQBC7FHA2guXKQuxcuDy/3AbdWKGNlSA4sg1ySXL9rhCrMAaMselbaFI2GHvf/Zqp7foL/mziTnyAK5AFXBBFaR@VYaI@xj7F0/87LA6I6e6ooWnZVkMrwlAGzDGIClp5FRdEYrjXX64Dhb1zwG87VceDc5@w@VxPScEM/R3GBqlNgcocu7r4uVvbHRztBnvFdvdw0rcJAjduIYudx2PxS/gTYnfptJ7GT@uxWOS8Hp/0/4X43Vg8HsfZdSDUmxjxCLZ3HkyHVfCDbAm9wjlCo5V888S0zktZic9SAIu6vIxtKrj06a9aZHOFZJlqKjg19clLDRpJzHYCD1CUcEIJhq98HmeyY8rLsfeFVso@Pji077sPDMYPUZVybbEeYxlVwrNI1YrvmxfbGycqtJGsmD1Jx9jdGO1oF8slTdS4RzXGTqS4WuEHr8bPyi@KL0ovHj8/fH74QIg1Ny42HFy0YOFeuzf2x1@DiPFsLs5Ysxab1XL@hmy1XpfUbQ2NpBVZBdh/Xy1ImYs6b@Z1CihoEPL2l36Qm22X4F3LqPCuafmUVq@rWxpLxsZvv/p9tHdzvv/p7iMWx6nuv/uTH2nFv/uTf0W7weKXNP2tZYsxiIlOtVCMnZ@Pz88v4eJh@VgrxpHKFZPg5ksxaqyuqFrWtu0qqyi6vlVM5bS7dlXx46pFNRnzpJi/qFTMx7wLP0jLlCAoWPUhL7GAVRLbPzLzmnp3eweKs5PNadUNaEZqeOiThX/bhleOCbHS45cXjMFLt94bDEyNXIrCKm8ktv1G2mZvcMXljbTBXtbquHKv4lHRYEViC4/O4apcvJ5StuIMtCNWb1xWL1spWtQAdfKFYWzZzSudoLmBZyeWvbZs@DO2PPrDRIGHB6/Bm7H1pScmtpKK0uuFRtW2DZavQ6vYUgC3rWBZgv9JUjP59pd@Q9MKf/cnv3bRvmh/roE@WS4XVC32s59tT@2pZ/TqP4OENxgyCXRCWtNBiyPoCHVJxk1/mn6q0CF3QY2d2ig38/iBZom6JMoc5sA2eqRZCqcoJ1FFtrktvV6Com2hnYM0yd1kuypZFYRQPiW52h100wSDbaFtSOjpwrnwAQbBYMxANq8KHyxAgccIhl@n2/asqTumkyYJSqe20uwOJIEcPkAzhRtkn8Hn5BJwP2XrelKOskdUI5mKjQzPQ6OHMAgJH0AS326uNWdjHU2JYEzThqFDxiiEJwX0GpB3C/K2eII2@Sao9DxCmnHseCIbZG/hAxAmiAomyBjM3IYIVWBLHwABoAwJH7DZYtssm2TnZipVXVhUvMQt82hyUg/MGAiYDKH10GxGkLiK8cALZH78UiO2C7@GQbyLeAZAOAy@wl4DrQGT0xsKbWRn5J1BASyy6ZWgorE7dxZY1WpmL8moRAj/xBzj5BfVg70aVwAWaFwf9ipimqGtymrgGzY7oHiK0IVWJ3EjldVIUibi66UgwP87N1pskVeqigKqWAC/vniv6ALJIDGSnddhl23XmKoVkyxEvgu4dwkpOk0eqpHN2Yey9nkQeAkY/iwWfAcFWNRxdELRb7dX7VgwGESn@BEKtGbGmYFvf4LbK0NWdzAJUoepoCimRbH7pgsKDi39B6YSE1k1ickWpiUJD9r1ruUYbj7PJ/FBqTA2g6eOJv/8fDbIVFHXgQr1xo5NNgLJhhFu7IcWATzKN6/G0Z7aZ/jRIr9uKHEUI49Mq2HLR4zJ5iF97ZnS4tp7xwU9OKBNmhkDmXVHPaaVWYIaGpmBs0NwSUpECHdAWkYadyxjBCg9Mww6@uVVFGUAwta0Q7bwHpvQroYPTBhvbE/xP6ytnJknpnKMH12QnD6eEOOWRWIon2H348v8vt05y3FOmGWeGHyeOLFkl8VjoC@AyJsGyi5@QNgK7h/RsmmcsFDTPBb8ivAocmcpHUm7kZgnrz@z6kaijTV6QYOP6eJHs091O0Jfui4EX0X25l5g2YnsE8G7HLJcw7fpUoujtYbQWJHg26iqkXkkGdcfxglQWAPbTugUxq5xylDZFXCMAabZDaykYC@G0n5AAwD1PehZaPJx4lbQtg9g4vYSXeh6PoO32YcsqwkYkRve8o1kAQys@toydAiDpFgOb9KDipFp0h35CvTOUQ/C0KqE3/wwfdC60U3mOBfNm2344HDQobxqjHeL4CUfecHege2Zir4BgQXAcAUmGwkxBWBTYlLkoMP0V5Pz1i4QL6mw65DSDCH4pAYoJCroyHLoG@eLrwsJEHBP97gJet8g5NnZmUxWSqeuKRsefnHHc2zdUsYDEyRqR5kYo7H/bVMTv2ntw124JP6hLXk8HO/MUHStle/M@VMQ@l7N34WTiPe9OA6Op/hBmcGILJqhKTGPGtQDkz5G1U34m4J4@9Na6fOg/VWw/Uml@CUCYQzBzNLzdDcNwNKd7km6f9ar@gGn1CEBONSiEXii7WA3eBl5gcsc98MYzgT5aBjUsU5oRRUgiXxmd5E1L2EQcx68@u9jcwaJbOOM7bquPk9QeBJjYwNOzEnsYXMY9ikEnDDMsHNuyNacNeatpeSzMDkMauF@AhfNlQnnNwPlVo0xfMbDZxA@4@GzRaZBto1Zi4tk6HWJxcFWj1Yug5gIZh7EueQWgBchBBmkb6ZyEBhzvuR3Cb9ujVIH9OZvUI@1oGFAmxgDwY2E0njRbDRbtmecbbVSygAau0iEgBoH0I0W0fSsF7qR@tapNXa8JS8bjZvCqOTjjV7dod8aeFvBMoYVRA2D08tEe5SDkb/xgQsEfoEBAsphEIiiwe4kYSaroRVtCoSG0xAXNOaINXxkWiR9@UG@H4hLnPScsFFArQgg9A@LBGhCCAt6Dv@@WsAdPnMdiBPEleiTUCO0ixZvxYGSV7oK5zVVqqQIVpIUoAlkR3G1drUoQThUReNKUKSYl379R9HfeG/0@9AvVmNPDZYPGFUh2lVwyyGIEH53Iaqyei1Sr4CBsqVbhgsj1z6XT/3RGrLZUgI1g@eDRfDO8KPxiUjld5O8fuhgo2iLlbApzGs1KOK8xrsl7xcBSTnBw2Sen2weNAQ/PWcgACOzMpnhJ5tFk81qNc442GxNsrMIkjNCcsaT8NizNUi2/GSgPR0EwwtWTwukU9wTKQI8lQ@jIAaNRYZfjscl8S/RZiOuJvh5LngOtQK/DaGIje2s21qZeyOCdIRpXQGADfEagB7/VGtFuMrwVCl8C3kUJ2XAo/ib3ww4r4AGRiy4yu0aJ8JGRjowCPxiisYB6LtiqiGIKs0L41@G/8R04Bn81OuemeWY6rJnJn3l7x/Es4WUjXTQiPShZnLIkFGTeW77BkGjMkcMv2o@dECq65w5LLFC2AZ/ZeonVTqW01FGOm5twQ84cl95PE8G@gOuqbC7Y2eiT5xcrsKVJpOa3ar8uc5gDmwHv/sSsW0Osl7PMTw7PoFK7ToD2/SMNEOzkyeGr3YY/mcZhKic7DsdTxD8GU2uxiJo3q5Q1G238ZPS7XYC9xEmK@HeaNpWiM0zHhdQ/wVXJD2wJx/o4TjhdL40upPk7TDRUL@f7NjsniQOx34gzr7uMuBhXZD/IXQIEgzznIXmSEbAUZTuTBL08ZOhM3IGIPVNPVnA1FfAHyxgI0L6eEy4pJmOKm0l8rkG6iWJblpP@kk/ee@k7BMtoSfD9NoygCVipJl7lcZIWXdFdu212fFkQX7P3h/fZ1F8n92ML2nhV3HmqnmNB75f1tnEAgJEXKCRvR0NLDrwrd41dJZQCb1RruIJ3hnFHm0d6yGmuxB1148u96F9pMM3D95CxD9dR/@bKzBIvv@u1adDt2fP5sBvRrglMkGf6vKCxdEERD9IIu@5nl3YtO@/Y14QF7@S@ABFCBBjiXHZaL8YOuYY1G4vnC4OAN/S5nG31rV2T1u4ajxwBU7uaZqdaOur6H67Z1j63Ogl/JjpCNygxEegsBG/ereCI6MjpudwXS8BY1cyDIVhHInOI1XWNBk9fZpMrm9WPIoZth6aKScMD9bTD8OvsWac4qvx2WrQA@LxGE7Hnpo4/Tmej@fcRL7FP9jk81E@/vCaROsNtxME6MBHTzW9yDZ5E/s8SoRFeocRIYwrLxcZLVgHENHA0fU6fD8S3V5SqNxIolpQy8Lyx2FW17h5U41HWkXQJvkq07s1ydsa3Tu3uUhT48AWLGzv/YaQa5BxP0e3m4hC5D431phjX@MJ6EfzdPaaUaW9gqGGKYnTTUxSt0m@SAqoGR/AEyecPoUnAhwYkzZvUEHZcE7L//Qho5CRPo5ILb4PCOkAJUJFTnIfjUgsIXBD9PPLMM/u2jy71/LsLuUZ9oDlLCORhO5Sln4tYPXcVAWW0Z@s4c4YhLozPG5i23DZju7ibMV53IxXzDSLn8YrwJDjRryynwCmHO/FK/fJ4cUrz8hxEq98Ao5F34pfxCtBt8AILryS4y76@ywc37vxyl4ieSlM9BPDC/KV45WwTiHODn8ligApsNwgNeISm@34xZy4BgxsJFSmGbYYL43qE83DpOmXgX/@uSf6EAwG4hznFkVmKaYuDRqREYPnA8NG8KGBFT254o/m@4cPaD9UGAWzSYGOF01D4EEMj8WXmRFHDENpRQOegCDyzcpqjFhkJHtHdPzcoYVSJS/nT9STSR7oJSi8AZFbi0zoG19@@qC@lkHwCnw3PDHxOjyvoRNkRxjhmmxyBVpI1JfxGwqFdb2Mi1/70Rqiue7lSICtFEThtURgIzwdZDhanMPMxs54uZFQKG7AN6NpaFKOd0psvVeSEVfwe@aaYPL2S4aMIdr5kzcVJ5IOUVtiQRjYyLR4LwvHBeLFGLTgdRFJlXc@QCHCc6CHG90T@n7afd9J8Ti7SdNYsW4YCtLyLIlzLbNJSCyjNaqpPuG5h8rrPtqoej/1NUg5w7mWBAKIpAxz4fzVeQ/53eHyeyBQB0S4ksEqwXr1UHpdvL5xlL2CubXI9noFYmCa3U@uFI7CHBYkB@0gIpnf1Nauifi45YML@TzTEPoVaT8gW6gT3EK3q7oFh4VSgnu67HmigeeJtp5Q1yUS61QOhBYZc/Lh8IKHmC6KdjOuvOCrqhhDaH5bt967gt3lCo5WHsKjArhXSM57uTu1aZfLom8D2@Y@yFLVCuOMnJZLw2peeAK7p6XbcNkWPA7bR/cPnzz6Ogy6xWIx6Y/R8wV@2GtxrjUcxzlk2lwdjgcr1BYtjR85wsVunI73ho472Wja4jVewpk1CAM65BI0P7@PJ31eFuHnV/oupONxIxT1YZ38v8Vd61IbS5L@7X6KQsJGDa0btjG2ELYAYWsGgweBfRyA5UZqQZ@j21ELkGxzYnZ/7Avs/t9H2FeZd5hf@xSz@WVW9UUIjMcbMY4w6u6qysrKysq65SUaBm5CKmGp42LK9jVdR0QQb5RZdDUQs7wleju8W7M5nE@j0XO7XqPB05eJ36pnMXSNuRG3/5Gey18EQw6dLLGoriyLvT6orT314U3lQB28qartw80/q497h@pDZfcABv/vDjd2apuK/ld361VlJbQuEbcPG0qi65bX9BCMVS0XCk8UQ97sDyYidzKbtnyvu131pt/0cE21FrjdV@fykut5o3UpVaXt6ARnmD7Haez6I@hbcGBB2sZicdNio0FYAyjKe0p72i72vN1@y2/7lNfC3nfge4GxM1Mdn3qQ5K0xe3ZkkYQYgqw6xLFBoYF1RcVdyo@7GwLjiv4VSIwcEnSwlVOacOG/H6bgQXX/bV3Bd8Tm3u5W7aC2t1tX23v79PruY233NdGzVj/Yr20cIokzvt3bqm3XNiv8QRAo5BScOvx6EYzuRCGH7EyV5m@4@c4NqPvDt@SpN1bw6spl88lALVz0IH18t@N/8VoLJesiwPIFJpt8VaAy85X91@9pzlfe77jhNFfBrH@QOgw4ruV8Qa1xbTRY1mm8lfRwpWkvW7T5PqI7UQht45XY2UOGnx1lgLMST8v3VGoTOio4@xafEDyWDWiqaI5gA5RRWCkrDkm1sOCsMch1qq3Z6cOBp9QmSoT6BUVfGVWTksUU07oyAAp7h1oP50HFUviB@J4@LOtqR0PJoB6HHySDeiIfsBStQXdEPdU5LkZ7FxDPakU@/NodbPO1sHoWfthweRe7qnGSfuMudVUY0g8eMjoceExOeTg4Kgd35iIB50dQrk5HBoYn4SBJJspVIuu2Uc4UCZs2rhq02ptEWUYqcQP0hNz2KFCZsp1TB1AO8nq@hHw767g9UYGKVHeY99QqnBGV1/XyIQyVxhYkgz4zIMI0JvEIy23pVaF333JUcuNGja7WkeRwpUYF7XsIbNxA4J8BQ4CyiZ1Ok2cqtmgFmH5bs3Im6BNH4tz2j3h@YufWRdNLFNBaW5lf/S9fbE1kJ7FPMnqKjB110RdvSMtKvsps94c0xlmscnApSMHmeX8w8qUPM8kW8I0TT3OUGxMb1fbZEFfXBjpM19jr92KVnhIX31LrKTHlfWpljpe781B8RVGHifNpEha9O6DjnvYvvdjdmYNLpCsPxy@0EOa7chx@TkaMiaw/rUh2/KEQrHS1vL61cZz947ODiKUiFiRgsFE6xH9iTNRFw4Pv@VhhcYh1lx5pJtJccHGK0loHT0tLjHIDjPaB5z7t6141SmGaqBvf/A4bm@nv/PHbt7KUykIy6SjTwXkmkm6OOjJVOlzmRGkVkJjsJGRJ1mfMF4dhhvL6Fexq0AvwrtODHMG@fSqOmxYhpnWnF22SLDqcru7uEL6t1lmjIopFDnuZeH/kP2U2ykvrdj5SKFExcmaMiHYM5KJtx9RSeL66AW7rbnAkv@8PbvVO7GR6@CFoW3dC@yHcsku3w5JpKQbr/mD/uAOsTG7/FFhqu3M7YJkkb0ILOT1kTmc@HWrT3l3j5xt9x2OPwGDuxQlKCDRW20WPr6iNv@yMFLDjYKIFUf1gq7q/r1KyP6GyJPewZWhpMQjYc@pdpG3r91jY5cJFU7hZDhdP5ktCo838u2swzyTeLaJCr0EcTY9QWEQettv@WKSenll4CcHa9ywQDeWS2H01Mig40oCvaQ9IyEadFmugNbOZaZl8/CCuBK7p5sjaOK7DzxrWMncjSO1wEgcU1wlyz2BZMrv/Psj6@IWpRxZY8EWEBrdoJU3zDe0T6lTxgDLmcskevKNbTJdCyV4W2GlDOyh@FZIr7J9nKGYkWYTLWjgm1vXiWKMm6@N5s8xhhURMAy40PXWiaDRTghHx/GUt3qF2NOllklMQLTIRtvRVnCuo@Mm1nsKYGuE8WQ4X5PGxNs/YHBksT3A6q2GXbs/0ELrQK9PiYboqkrZ3VpX9/6lKZolETYbmMxtjEgnyytOnj78He7oVpnj2Z2HLHDItP0fdAe3vI5DBJODjfeLc2q5j0iMGuIN0olpvBsxUQVrqzJhTEm3nySiOH@Ei50KEDHzIIxLsdK22Gk/hNhu6zEhx6JzlRhtiQzhsqIyaG9S/vrs6COTv1jf34/XJYEMmqA5eQyv/bX8YeJFVXszFS@wTrGGT37zhsMfZxJ6pCygZNmO609iOre1E4VVahUS@b4u3pK2tk0Tt1jFnDVwJHy/mEPwZp3ul6eO9bLEUb@p2baeqFtmnZDtxFpkapuyY7Jnze3chwDKYzyUwfbAN38PgBf0nHBwDksjE1nwZpo39XdyYIrRqPuKIQlotVMvW4nTvt4Om24NTECf1MFAp5xEV5FPY6t62PetkvVBKlCfkgkEvQ6WcVDaX4qL0DQe6gJQEIb2J77EJC5YaRlMS5jVnfehH4WLLG8vpGWtOuvniamHlucWt6zkjp3v0/MRZbJZTiiZft9cNLoZXrd/O@ueXbdVRg19Px83Jl9@VevpEPaa6lh@JY9/iSjnPvlSf0d9V9bzAnKsRfMlOihGMOCdRWpVaUNE@vDSnbH7gTfMLWEhMcala7BouhIndqNw9Wjkp98qFUveod1KCkd9oqTxaKi5l8OERzaIkY@Rm/mh0gjk1furq9S4V3GdyNFBtGqLYNIS@vHWHfn@nsvs6cRqHBQCOwLSuNx@oS@DnB9Bmg@1JruddZfQxmaPAsRYWSNYDtgoqwlSez5NxHNPyCTPqFYdWs8GY/05s60EhdzEY9TnFeEkEa6lv/jfrgTFjKvCJAmU58o0vRdgXEJwoTwYXQ/J1IlrU2aIs14qwnbRjII5QksVh6jiVgk0hENW2XEcnVpDz3OY5kECk829cTK2tcdxzYrUgx6d4UOVwh2wwUTjBIy5A6GfAtw2oglfuAZt9WNR8vBfxIF/4jGrEdjKsIG/xShEpUP9WX9m@icuvEQGE8A9kzZXTR5x65UULSbEd5MMFuD1LbvxxzQCzSumUB2gsYEt95Qg4a4ozjVCtJhN9f3AFcgqt6J9uQbbIbzeaEea3JTuThO@p9VsAWnKXctI6fjpRsUysWNYUM5ljpHjwXWrgpIu2R289GlYTtel1OoS00OJBRA48sn2vrn8prD84Qp0nIfKSnr2Rnk2k5yRdkIpy5WiCjzK9iGdKpb9G@a5VKsrm3KirrHjxkqOebuZoSRLlLd2VN8iN@g0/yrwedqVwZZiwlkjIxlI@zeh9SZlLlAkZPEw/knTN38u650MsE3lfJevHr6U7yGPlWa1rMsWluZ7feWnpINk6BWyWImoqJcU5DKIyg6qsbTC1OKEVHM75ediulyMoS0UjcXjMpNbXXqVyepHxMjONhlgx3hhYM8ZIjEpc5xITbswGi1QPJ8/FQDBMMJoyI3fdFJ7owpMYWOSaM9WKFeSNAU5Nmx7iZdhFfsMfM9iTyJl86dmJDwTzsTRerJuTBGKhO5eaTaakNIG5iHzUjbpjFonqnkxDnC0kdmOnwGGdnthgt3EMPhfKibigMJLiBt3DFE3pKEPRsO9tXYjEa@sf@UXrtUtr7EHHG6sKthkuW2FZCQP3kReMAviGYhc3wcVg0MGtIy/4rtiEWrsVWX6K65YIYmxmz1k1aPZIfgdP2iCdCuXUHiBfQUEkSgguzs5gTAYL2P4VRCtOXPxRzqr0JnKgQWPm8bKYmXsKzjdYAHf8szgS0nMyekDpYOA2vZxFa7SAVj@WNLXt6/ChfJ4OuxF4H6Mp7YVl/eXCb/62@Rr3uc@KhcfFGMku9XVwIff4SWRgRUQyCctwIPi0@MSyYnfDTbkbzgKgo3Yw0b8n3vQuvV7Psyo0Y3DGgBatgTe89Fo5y9r3wktgwAUr42YSdtj9i2FTDndo0eUSM8JKOHDkOow4DL@Yn@W6uMl3ZY6FS6votpm6@tJvgYDG4qTdx@0wX1jATYDQA4W63oiIsmirJEp896xx4bVLFwdRRA34OYndTYRk6PVHfpN6hk@yrA6BkmuQqLJeawoTqq/ZcWEcnJuFAMxjIgoYBMxV0l04WPrS/IdwULph5o7dNT2TJ@nX57FCw90b@iR9IwJzr3CxGO7UwQdvanVV39s@@FDZryp6fre/9762Vd1SGx/5jhsX5eyTV73Z2yHpEt6my635Hn1IVepUMsUJVmX3o6r@8m6/Wq@rvX1Ve/tup0bQCPx@ZfegVq07qra7uXO4xbfvBEHt7h2ondrb2gFlO9hzuFZTzIrKqb1t9ba6v/mGXisbtZ3awUeucbt2sIvKcKtfUe8q@we1zcOdyr56d7j/bq9eVWiYtVWrb@5Uam@rWzmqn@pU1ffV3QNVf1PZ2Zlq6N6H3eq@YiWBWCs3qoRlZYO2sKiJ27lV269uHqBB0dMmEY8Q3HFU/V11s4aH6i9Vak5l/6OjgdarfzmkTJSotipvK6@pcVbmO1Shftk83K/CWxIoUT/cqB/UDg4Pqur13t4W07pe3X9f26zWS8ra2aszwQ7rVUch3iFXTTCIWpROzxuH9RrTrbZ7QHPG4TvoO9jUyR@IMIRlhYpuMYGhBoHWEpH29j8CKujAHeCoD2@q9H0fNGVqVUAFaFRsHsSzUYVExIN4M9Vu9fVO7XV1d7OK5D2A@VCrV23qsFodGWpQyPhIrEOVHnKr0U@ElzwSs1qGcx3uTlXbVpWt9zVgrnMTB9RrmluYbJtvNM1zcNUbO0Tx@zgzcLvxg5X2zU@XHpxT3jyRmX1GE3pM2tzbqtKMrF1bpaKEQ5p1VqdcKcXTaKYJE@k14bKm5Z1enDX8XrsPG9OwmBx8dIMzB1F8bIRAObbuCGalz1e4QDrdaLyvNGijW280bOc@JRNofK@EPga/K5et24jYCNh54@DnxQuh@1qCUOuP9EUnK@rhAgI5hfqPRPXN7Xq2yudbni4G430ANkdHgVybnOMqhUQjGzsidktUJZ9M8Luv2YELZgz4XLOBc1JoRnKmfkB/et@iF5kcYh9IOstxVz6PTSyj4X/xTDVSCbtE4D/aI4Hf5ipzgef9dpYpxKvDnj931u@3MrZtynDeEe0DzzL2d4qfemdTxbPT5RlZvnbWYQUCs@/mJUx4/6xJpnS/5Ibcsgz@NEb8YxtsxOcDTk25Kj6s1oeWmUdSHBpJjtKuLWBewZ2MNd/byi@1D9jNFZaflKa@vwm/y9iCviDc2NKEd8TlTvjnzYlkoAHGvjiIJL72kJHPx8oYfZMw8xVlPEemK78FzR@aq889nteJJLSQvXA78ToxGw/9cRx7ksOv9ytvNw63t0l0Atsnq0@frZSs0O3WL478fkQ97GmWvY4NaB6ndRonxUbJJi18eKTEHH1H7M8MnM8jI3y5m07jj/DzEOptJDWZIMjQ3ACBjHpQ0Ut5oENKsQOOOcvw68yRqRkgk2iqjdZ03TEv8V1aKzEPaGWWzoR7bYw/gB0OfzPEwwZpBtIsxr53iXNpd8FyL7VtVEV5c8OOe5AllzJ8LG7cQhrwURfrz8K6lt80b8d6MRBVRoxX7nYuSUjMTWOhjF5FT0b2O/Yzog@A2XsYfflF8xs9ftQO7tjdnRuMKqM6kXE7LIlz6ugwWjf6SEM@QVwNOFUzNa0pnPLbGikee/o4OXQMEhsNjAqCtkDHNwm4FPoRma6SNWBfLdjqq3AqnHcATklzrH4nzp3VHA2lZPyH6HfjlUIJrNDJiVDtKqzDMlk@hn4sDDkTZPopejD8fyFNZsBfox0nQY@oFXMCeC9KMlShFW1fmSj@lbloiN1uRNSMf/oYgbmOd8x52DB9ezMW@xoige6difnwkd0etjMzCAAmx8FGfPyGKmnnLm2dXqVsXRz3JL1md5BReq4wU8UNuNmVE4eXXY65W8GLrWw5a4pVuENF1SvZuJ3yqKct09RWXj0MUgLONv4/8ot8ABIOeObSc9Faneasgh5lRg5oV0uxCacVekyiZen1rbd2iyrmIjMh@/XNlyEUgV4HPjfbyUFG@krUc5MeF3kmVgfsBQ/@xLFNxuSjXdadsiJmxwOchy0@DEEcktEVJoiOQGdXfRE0lXnIiiKoJNI6jPwMQtzaOSItT6tXIfZ8MgkODbE/7Ikre09OtUyOnDj40BjGzeVz6q07IZQ792u2sFh@sd53oLuIyuRYQpdHzJVmvz@kpaOLdhOOjj@xc@qDPnTwesHFUPsvpPnMH@oTCbPop2qwbJLdO08z4kOeUQv8EawVWjnmD25S14OGqLgnGWdXVIaY1/Doujl09MdLRZVZi1LWiCbslpSJuKZW1LdvkksIql2GekxBPwg3F6yzyfXg3iEcflf94W@Y@7EE6rW8VuiZNAaSzwKlk2o99vHYHEnTB/2ATzSoK3ACElKiKAdpoaIqzdHPNDtpvaZU5B0Tvku5JT9eT8ikRluKKooYV9dOzLeSpc4ElZa1a9DQWWhx@SmjMmvDdX3rZoy9hSavrVXquBeKlBeyiCg/NEtHPIncDJ8@4kkf8pcfBhg99AV33HoJCoSxZsW96k05x/hBp@CD7w1b8TNRWsm03AGO33jr0@8xL5qjQ@32r@mOAm9CO4Bm3h/nGUYj86f@ea@x2e@4Z37fd2mfBjfwY5F4eJzwIzrsbNi/CjicECe0Yplak@hZ/MuIGza8h/eSpZhrrmDkDTJxNYXRcFI5FzcRfHIOJcAouijz92DaR1pY5snTqJCVtD9lfbyiXbq17OPirMJyow8AWsCtT2lQiA3piA2TYsanpRsZTu/KEMPxVGWVa9@isZfA@DmRiK9hEhgbZG6oJcQbgZ3ZrRgftcZOi30QDuFoydvyEBEnyPBnx0XAZpIiL6Ep8EIVVwuxonKLMoYfQjxMbif38rN/MfaEwE@gX3w8i1tmMQKLuLbxthTIfkV7GSVcWD3QZxnNkpikmH/m92LmhxyEYjwNNZk8uY0arPlDiyLtZu8GV2JEZmjjg6h3mQaJnMbExqSyoBZs9tuBJUhllCnczrDe9/RnefDjEldOziCYNjXkTAzp20jVJCohJO6Uem0cZfGp/P0Rs7x8316bImB5lspZLDRzJmVWLmyB4sv8imut/pCEcWqKelrVYyEY9QcL96TerbJjpme2WbRu2vZ3FYGF2co0WS62mLTlCR4nJWsanymmSVKMNc2Ih7B95eeQzaeJOC43MN7Kjcl36HAbzSK9qXBSCfu7JWMfk@IlNHrNRBMOKcYdTkpL4fejBjW8cbsE0TBle9VgidGAyGhM5DEGaopMIZXuTyHmPo37FD1aRDnU2yLaxfvnVqJOK8kZl6cmKeHkEvSE43YYbZJcGrShfAE3cbLCDYVUuOAcOxO@yitmT@FkGAkCEKtiLxudQ8kJbtRZU3zE0QHamQa0hYqQRPS0HtdwCJ3@hwRjr/z6cEdrPDQm2eJJSSCNQ0i0q@Bcd0Ey9ub0etQYM5QbpKAhPoMUYYtuyKbz@7fqZ9tC@QiClOZkrelbcNAYWy0RNvQnntQYYw0cVaVLJkZUciA0WDTQWKBdylnHk@0qVn/@UDge2g16GNEGQj5n8LOkS8Cd90ohpDaKjFsTZLE1uWW02Sq7LkUihpJ3kF8PRVnq8saVAHiCMZUvFwkC3Joy9rgUYNc7cc5LIKr7iAqWixiW9JG9okZ6njPSQVSd4cnTWI7CrBzP4zCyM4HQwmJ2nggRWrPMzhJBoYluJi6xHM9mtyfKQQtiw/tCceoK3StJGoY9JwTkINAFO5IoR0XlFDQHc@KTp3YiMeRvTn1eiKUWplOJPiGGR9nidOpqIZGaqHZ5OVk0UZLoYcdrTSQSKew4wqFU@Ll/bJoSd3ke6oTGNhmJVYbWz0aQbtpl0r4t92ug1tgo26wxDLy4ZbjZfjUkxErCKfvdDtjVAl8ZwHf7T7fWaKYaTHSsAPZLZ4xdMrIh5BVrClM9moWdrvG0FzooMHvaflu9P9jeTrh9PZ0YRaOuN3xaKBTAxKdx5/dGtxpHSX4/n8ydb190OvnB1Z@G70/zLPs9j0MCvDA7aI@6hAZFkOsPzyQyBHCgrMid1Yas2OtftNvxEAy4oUTnUbdJTu0NQfEE5IdKL@8P@ACIQeoJ9jMaiPZ9VuHou3JloamhmGsoKg2V4MuUuT0j8uBDG/rZ4U0VA4NgNtpMNG/Z5fWvmEEQ2YQ7i90X218j9eTUG6/T6TvqAwISw1PAg@vpAtvb8QIFyYIbRrbuvQjYH62jvEu/E7MrRpY4rwOcmZhMnAnjFx6@8fe9s@p4kEkdfUrRtEJNXkIzl@Cf2lGps5StncXfA6zwIaF9r9xdd5BpMp2mM9NUr0dw9EQYPS46M/c@iSw2n4lpmn0/N4g6G90cO2ugptu8FjC@7Ll7uSW3ZA@JmzoeF9ugYUFgaJzgc@V@JWBq9q8Ti5ejdvt@UpHDAEjH/pBElEgoPycQ@Q6AR6AefkRPeNH@c5aG9faUQxFZ4CBYx025gwINFLCsh83y71eZSqWi5gdLS6pS2aCHbFZVNipqCx82NtQWvW/g/VF5@enTksjcLfsrfdwwH6/VBsHgE86l5vlwi14prQy7MWhro4vn8@V5pzTfKK@tl4L8UWUDZv309Pd/@4@///t/5iv65b/xssEvR5/CTLlcLj/f/Dr/6LqE96Otk4X506P5wcnCWQlc9g/2Gt6vjbJupD6aG55aaZkFYl9Zj9Tss9n7jC6qTEzArjv8jaTLC5VuBvm0/hpI5CiWsemmF/vuwY7ylLbwJujA9FaekEgT0AmO46l3mh4U8Gi@IUoSLtADlfJyt2IO7uEOJswQ3qqktSceXrNeerBpiTwpwBaXZqys3wu8Hk7AL3nNK82zLJd@/VFD82/@09vgbKM/VovHGbVYUIuOWkyl@Ke48py@2vN5H9a5ko22A6mUQynR1QLUDFXg80KP9w8ca2eK3JY1zyF7AMm4qeDMYgXnhLs/NpaRgGvBmfUAoTiVHJHwJROKpL/O966pW75SjutUwtSGFwoNvYvhymI3KmH/YgnkBqIIENXcFYK86FOVuOlji2Q85c0X3dcWRxNiwCDr/uttHvf4QHPRfE/rPCf2UghzxOrz8hVzY0mMoRltpEj9EQJ8oSLbyQJbEi6kFyzR8o61kpspVtjx9mnmE12HiTcyuulS6A8VYwLR5o4Tbr6n7Vq0Irdcr6iUH16vxKpKTet@KytWpHvRGfkDba7AtWNAfQ1ru5aRhB5lQAJHfPa/uDnC@KDAeIqa6hYJljVRrT6aLiOhp03TqYPtnNwcxYiQ/5Shsf1tamzbebYSMewgPMBIhap8bdfvBNrrypCJfeYOTxEd0G1zQLWR3JvxeR6ir05h3G@HSOcYMqucR@OZmpIeDN2zruuo9G7/YOhOajRt0cpn1MzZ1EK4YAISGHy66lnNMwhLi3SXMEXCprDmEIIXdCY6PJr0bSq0OUGXmqGg3a5gECTYiSnpfUv01RQdI67@gU6Io3xDeIe3kVrEsuSFppGGlIqbzfAwuzF0LFNDfOyEAydlCarhyDS8oAtdYKLt8sUvSfIOfAToulPaClCbIqw8R/2Ync68npuYnAYdyxj650tK5kWMZw5FKdpIlomTWowi3gErWkd@SnqBkLnJuDOyHmQyD44DHc4tHZ9H2Ml3qIufd5UfBqDjAGZsGaIOe74Iy6kZKoqBkVM11vwnCO2Oe0b4Ta7cCVjxOJ15OZe3jz4d904WM8e9b8dfbMZEi2Qzy2ZVWl9mG4mlxwrNjHkn8Wq00gLjavC4l8xw3FNiwxIjASGSzxx9yp98yxNCx2lEpT9OC0ESXQZM8nfXlwf4/A0000ks8mnrgb1om87PvCzaiuZW/kUfygdbfgkLs6nkY3ra5wzbBIrtdH@/EJOTIL@6XHiyXHxCO6Ezb5wdeheYb7PBxak3pqVEgO0sTT3HXxLckCDE9ThwS/RxTO2UsCZiexJoIyUtQvUw53qskK2oTE54gvITldldKkxc7DCPi8tHbPgdRSxn8rIvKFEdjHFfBvNn0O@iHjeAXJu2DhGOhJaB6IjwEWoWkE3wlds41DbDZYHtnHJqE75bGQh1bz4dmy16/V5WL9bs3EIJi2hYzXRWC6uF6TF6Y4gmRui8XkwtzKni@stnf/uvvd/To/T6cv7DkH5H6d/TK6tpeaQHents3i7T6@k1ZFu5Tk/ytAemx2d/@x8qv/4ngoOUyRr9WX9qYK1M0uvZMhf5ll5foYfi8jLV@79//Su1YV52bIjFOt9wFCNWMhTZdHvMu5SuamilbEsXIrHChlmAIRqGtDenFyhGjZdXC3xMl9ZaFZee9nxl9FH0FM@KWSNWFZKTDKNPQSsjKVBGBVkBaVQo2iqmu2HUNsC8EZrq88PcSkA7gM9anSOsMlTdeBhAZWhetkXUgRmpkfbz8rBeeJkK1TtepIxOScksIbG107J29XHp/wA)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/my2hz)

fish [recognizes](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#quotes) `\'` inside `''` strings, so it executes Ruby/Perl/Python code.

Changes to Ruby/Perl/Python code:

- `5<<64>>64or 68`  `eval('5<<64>>64or 68')` to fix error `Expected a string, but instead found a redirection`.
- `exit;`  `[exit];` to disable exit in fish, but not in Ruby. Note: `exit(0)` is [invalid](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/P7Uis0TDQPP/fwA) in Python 1.
- `"$'#{print(187);exit}'$/";`  `'"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';` to fix error `$/ is not a valid variable in fish.` (same for `$'`)
  (`$`s were there to fix Pyth).

fish code is on line 38:

```sh
echo 353;exit;'
```

To fix errors about wrong redirections the rest of the polyglot is hidden inside a `''` string.

The only problem left is `'('` in C code (it is there for [RETURN](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187655)).
How I tried to fix it: `'('`  `"("` (breaks Pyth)  `"\("` (breaks Cyclone)  `//(` (on a separate line) (breaks Retina)
 `//\(`.

Answer (score 1):

## 354. [oksh](https://github.com/ibara/oksh), 15920 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubx b t c u c 11  .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo 354;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';                                      # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{














































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hatax@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"ullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!!92[ ]?42e>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD4o6Ph/SNSoLpIigRAgN@kSJVKpepSd1WpRqXq7mmSxQJJkEQLBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uPly5eZL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuypY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3V46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbUsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6TzaffLRlfhqhn2kA1Jjy5hdyV5V2Wem4fauptDYp8cPHlz1zbJPJMdmD66jpObY7nTiHEyuws@z3YFh60yTy7J2NbAAxJwYVilTylwNKkJ9GhOzu5QPBDwwXahd3a9F1tVtqC2syy1mjMaTOZN4/euWFdatx3SPTb2pblE8ezrqGG4Q0Zvo7sS0B@zMnAzZZGh6YTqK7Y31riH1DMscmROjxywTEjl9HwqAtnvsxJifOS5UuQ/Tsa05JDS6Zt/EJAEeABCvxGRocDgjfQ6VbE@gcTCdeYCGZQTQkkIM4t83OtMBc6aT8XTCALee6ekdC4B25qxn9PWpNUmzDoQBkcn/bGjYfmMGcDKAOHY4Vl9OCTVj0eb1Xo9loB0DHicGM4FqhFaFZbPgzxwXqAaxAox8YNSueRmNGdQZVFHfqbB8JgPh@6EPYqtbnuMjs4waBtrQV6nOEO5T1xm4@gio0TOIpp8ePGVe13HhDX4Yl/enm8B09Qnb3mbx/Sf346weVovsdoSwimrsHKogFgSyU92aQguJ1oQD9eOGqQWssvhGvMLiQBYtw3I5loNuW2JaHoikZsrggP6vZVX4FZhWYjkVelA@nsZ8@q4@MC2DQxkglCI2fC3PNLhnciyrlnjMgWP1ebQuZVZk2RIrFFkxz4pwL7OyBrkh6BxTy3n4FeAH0MqAigq/bI4DWrR7aKfY1vZYXx@Z1tyHTuC7LK@yIkAEfFWArJUAAjyzWfxl4UdoLV9R2JMhUHuonwJ4yTJPkBsZIUPCKlTgoWxtKcQRkeXy7L0hZg@kA6LlS6wI2ReAEjlAASirlSD7fIYXxBsaluUnG3qYjLAtZuAHmBeBDiWgfgZomUFiFuEH78DvNGBsGnAxDRiTBsxE08CdxSwgXgHCClCVBZ9eQ907gYx4PlqPiA8cHcCoSG1kYioSCSBAbbEs1FmB5aAhZLEh5LMM8AdcigUGfKykslKOlYoM6FnOMKgbFfDCVqIC/1QBHxWBQf2r0ABUwEkFaqsAVM3mmRAhtprFcEibhbRAGjUHaXLghopTC/iDdNAyVMhShTw1rbxohICblofy5rPUOrUC1G4RwoBuGuCqQXPSAFutBOGYtgQ0LGHjLcbTnBA60gFqBZs7tEMgRh7wIbgQF9xaMcvpp1vjod5Bbs1TdvqYtIDdoIBkhKQZLB48c0hNQCUDYLAXAPoatIAskCMLVZvNYfaXAnRgPlxH2R9wic@w6yMzQ4YNzMohVrxokwk7YDdJ4I7LnBNYmQVtE4aLro5sDTu5QUwqgGNOZAaZwNhqOKcoCxCnWcrGI27UcXHoh6GjZ7guw7ggL3hp4lvetOMZr6Y4OC3w6gMjNIBf9nXTChGgzqlPiKvCM@5BfvNltPuuM6IePEK@ZDnOeM0YAFzwDAE9dM6MBeoLJqmPxxYMReBv8JEQkDnTSYghiSeaK0cIEmG67tAEgJQVsHDTNbpEe7/okDoLzH4ZxQrT6neyCOVeZIzKsrED/NvDNPbUsioweBhdlq0rPeNUQR8@ji2PX4hDMLLB@OSD6OgggCDmhEUI6Y4m05h5HNSs54yWi8aZ1kFY9KGJo411ps@h9vrAr4yZPgIxiaEsYsMIOYIWw2sQawIEQSzWAes5dnwSQjlzQTKAQoclIekDaTIxRwaIlA4kwRrPEdLIMgmzzhyaMlErJ5MMyTG5QihZuEoo7pGLePDOAmNob9pFqmHepk0tCMYeDwUn19B73E@YuKzZ1OHnwiA59sVmGR0Y8RmiFpG6YIQ1gPq@ONMliDjwG7YHsponMxOFWmj5A6cPje3MhLKDuARJF7C7RAQkQeg1k7uyQCTHBjQ6sZjJuuMxA38QQqB5PsiUYFx3vjTZawi0hiCXdaeuO2ezMdSEOYJYk67T70PrfW2MhwCCjXqsO@9C94RKxtYj9BziSN3xcjEXb5sGxLFR0tt7@nU2MIDsIAX0UeTHJr8owHhMRSBS6DaXEGwdKIVF6I7nRBYAE6boO46M/j3H8KixOO5J2PUxM88YUNeAftZfMKMRSjzQSm2S1HrAefzuhfAxQ2FlYTArvxV8ZNjQdbrQKqHTQ/Vhne6yPmguEbkAhTe92zXGE7@dOMTOTDsiRB0@QCGKfCUfmOwNhc27bPtKq4GoYcuJCAgoVCLqY1@205HX@uoRiAy2sZDjOWex5teyhxinV3IXX2KcJQxeimtwGFOXQImSmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3ISEGeps7vV588Itm746Y1A/zRmxUYDuCrIReiMd6GBL8rOuA5LGFsOpLHhh1yeMW0Lo3WgHZCZG0elFfWdFlYIq3AR05trMCKhAzhItRlkOoLqgxPkOuoVthY6Tu4i3VETLshcaOAxmMoeOx40LP4ExnTuoZVVmkdflaTSIcK5Kg7S8PrTBkxHHAn@AoCAnGFuhy1MWwp4K4qgOnACbGtQ7geQ7PMYIw9XqC5eN3RqyfNyYYS23bQIlXd@ccCBQPhmfIaM5M1wU2eIqDBB@DgsFEpnYKYwLoX8hZkRzU769mLmOL3pt2zNlV1aaLnvKXnnCqu6yPWo0LQgd0okS878WTVfKnlJEgUXHGE4WS8rsIESmSDFWe6IOiBIPEA2A0z@Z2NyEudTExzcTppF8Sk@DAhFxGYx/r48lV7L4EP2w0oxPo1/RWZQMYviUJ7hL6ESYYoMgYoLsgZ0AnBNG9XO51dHYB3ANU9NkepUYhk56qnAvzMuxemJdPCMQlWl6ZZ@G5XXJIkVENS4DRqeQ0SCwR8B0pQQlF8FAUf2xFD5L2eBjJNdxzatPkBktwUSTJzkNhHwaABCFjgvBhds1J2xdX7twJBJeNWg0aG0hTwDZ7yaiaEMwCycCpIbJM0oifiTxxnk2wbySSUF6MfMmxAbEJWmqtzs4nQxd6HL1fChAJyCrY2JIDwvr1/MQ8mfauVrSNnhhJxF4HQpPZnYhVAQZ/3htqN1E1vkRVUCXiSFVsvJieQF9rvOSLFSr60VzDQ/G35qMSqeEEYuC31ZUk4kl9v0WD3pt3LV8k4C7o7JwbdQD9E392IGREaV8mCDrttZ7KgWB34HDY093jhzW/L/JApWPalSUPy@nqFnlvYnQxSPvo4N7R7tHX2ytgWGanctVDMXOlAg6105k0sKdKTtYqm1EYC8D32zfDxoTLcUTBD2aSM4uISvMuDC6zgJyHR59cJQlIQkgOygHc@Lsi0vA4IHQJHd0bXhmE2SCVgizDJEFcJh2wAGboQNQxXA/weTp9/Ror7ypSY98fMbOmOgcQeCoHdpBOxsArAlgQ1OnzEZHSghRq2jh7u3BFYwb4fIRS81VkSJSONJmPDh/sH9UIrD9ZIVEUxZuALKW7PRnavDXtGcKqOMD@wNVlKXmBOMrThOtKAne7SwRe1C1bAx8AoK4jO0yyRkHRvCHgvne1bOQrdcMWQO8E4apcGZWHuu@LaAQPHOK6qPKuGkUpYDFYhV4rR6wwdHnY6ubzRjFXjg5b3UWevShQmmmFcSCQG10IOvEk9JEXUqQvVvvoP3t0DXGPhEhQBaQAM89iMuXlWQJqL5LJ4p6yBxqaYxnyZ8TxRCYmFSUeTLbKXY@Uz0j8/Zk5SWSS/KkmIS7kvrt7oN0PIvvzgDSTQUoD6uI4Mrl9XDTpetBGbMdyBg7bgjRcOgwyBLFpbTF3B459rYZ09MSixnDdBfgvTtzoYxhrzNekOFKqqLrKV3B02zsDLq0WskgkohCBUii@/KV@qgO5FuV@dvDFPgwiaj6TCd0ZuoAEkTRELnR1I77kwSTISPbxWVnAcA3mWm8PAqTIIggW2md0YcLdRfBKT@KYsrIy/kqUPnauUfxLZ36laYEPb1rgiJDs4MnTRwdP9h/vft6caPn80nsuUy4A4SC/DshC8pDTDXvrFu@aWCwEF4O@4WL3Ai4wBQUlmIKfei4wbhmjyByBNa2Gr14lPnaGdtxLXi3MGYZKX9pd3oQeY@fjUf2EoGj3LFRGXL4EiOM5tp/hZDL2KooCvXw47cigtCpfdh1LHyiUDgYGy1JUVF0ODnFew1uVApDx5gZPwSe3QHSY0wyibo0cUF5oIRFZA0tw8DRrZZmDIejCuNpouEk5bMFUGqUHGgLoykpYNmLA9Aa09Z9BPYm8aX@gaiXertWMllPEINpS94e4G30DVKcEjFZAiuSVV9a807zD5sClEdJVIDEmb9Ekh8dwLLAYCJI0a4p6fkAc4hY4X4q8gmj0aoqzucCllHwmV1QLeQXUMlDTQGaVcM5NGumT7lCaOBLAk5w@zRtEWmHf6@p2X97yHQGyIPd9CEXNNl40m3YLBPTmHcINF/Ma81ZDbSWr7HqSLT9@sgqtd6l42HYDD2i75ISmSU@2hp/19OvsrKdT7@oxZTIa@2OONGaPd0GQeu0Av@4Z0b6HCZRooLK1FFfByG@UFRNCFiYV8IaUUqBDwUgLTU9BvCQQelE8hJYDfCuSgC1mM3g5@KJ5hI@g0o3t3nTiHs38o1yDs6XeGIhIk81d5NIezg9OYHQMWz5yaahcZNLszIjjPLru8dlKSOQvnAbpQVcLIdCsfDgjbYdLxdAIKBWp58A5oF3htOlwMcuISj@0NMiQcMLJB5AgbFo9GACfgcS8ILu8IDwn8lku0ontnNkIrWOwktQxJ3yy35m6uIBo9qJlg@hZjccBaFS4CF@nlcaO0eWzrDwxlQKUQJ2NjJGDUwkgXRErMKgIOl@lRF3Qwxlr6FYZCZdhAL7E7u4BF@safL5IGqESBU1qn8UnrrIrfaHo0mtozTfIVlj4SBX7lX4cEGB5zZhmSfwZUJJOnBFF@ozmWzDwXiDuCuP5ZAglhhYm6jVnbNhXdT6uESaSVVrbjceB4Zt24jy@sbERr8Tr8TS4dsC1ja4ddKXAtUMuiVwYT0YXpUiTC0MblAL9WvHLRgB5lmxhG5ih5PDaHCf0RqWSbaX1huo/NXwmoSqA8hBbwgfAiSdrNXQmk2L9DNdsQH6PlH0P286zrmuOfRJ8DAIBf/dpkCUigHqP0rxrVFE3vZkio5oLSqOBImbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TSmTlb1GuiHwLwmiZE8cJ3pGAS3Rq4iAW9LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIz2Z/LCUTOmc1om4AW0q0WzGgaQ@dRrdoUvwZmktmQwJBXj0TdAyLCsRl89LkH8n2Uqm4pA2GU8DW67F40CXLhLBo0LjjABvRA/MGZASOiYMcdE1BWKQtDiF3fULYzycu9EI4awbSNk4g77YAID7JJCLR7nka54@KtAtafqB3MvjgXCLk3coL43nnLsLHNOmsrTdJBh3T6X@yJnoyqcyKE1yZLiMb8QVSYKRkEI4JCr2Y9PDLqzbhjP1ojONKydAMXfwPR5OgVkGe37S0KrMsWB0hw6Lb94F6Cxc78GhBJeuJL4AFgDodWX4IRNFqQQXS0C6oF0aJvBF2t9CszIqIcFZTzA3ny@MX8lhblVKwzKYkTmwHdeQgCSQQqAtKbTRSagzf1fMAc18XVuX8ENpSEPF2zSAIz6wHJ1oy9l1ZD1oPIqkB/0ckhwZPcEC/tEH9ijzunCNnrIl0Cqt4w5hhIDSICfWwtoa@QGK44178mQGSYUEDrjRQK7dgdB5xnqaphW6@X4lCMNWAcQeQiWhVmqDihsESSoEJv1K3ufTQoGO/uTw/j6fO6HBFodXnEdrj5zeFORKX286MuxBmu1DezJtZ2QCGYL0r0@sI8eZcC0fXtbNzHCl2RxNLZ3mfK5Oy9yYrut0HIumgm5Kuog/dT3d0vkkVBC6@@ljkPWfHz@ryZVIJEU/Hd2YN85Drs6W0/MguuZI663B8pDHG6a4mRdx3Aq20iGb8QMKGDD1N9JBHQX@RfQPuhSuofj@JfQf4SY6kJX9WQR6DT39iGWKiBvrcBeR73muZi7Rf60OFsZTKR4XHBfYnqsa@Z9O@v0l7yx5n0jImqyFd468@Qa7JR0xilKeR8LddktxooAKFCfcdLc2XpHijWkHnhyuLD4ONyEMDStYWjwCiQWXz2DQt1CuAqUFRXS@Mc4ACXuMqyTEunHtjXVBCPWuzWdAZxtLPLYQ26AOBIObgiKNsKkwf@67Sl3Idvw1S4@zVQd0fppW2a7zVW7UqVyuzil8Vn6zDSC269VgF9O6aJhTPB5GI6iEG6SgYtLC/rWihts0PJpsFyhJVfAUUCdmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrTPQS/BLWibd5SBUcUM19GrGoTEfRm2M2cSSHwYi09cd4fAZ1hqtkxKqJ@p3XesnsRXyaDBMK5fYQX5mxTCrXH@DkjDdINdcbQtkSdF/hrZUHcN7pUqrV@PENmCFwKC7nPOLk7SpxesAUPeqeyNLXPSYpfyxGkPkSSTqWtf3azHZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdo48@bWRaHIIw0nHlq8RrcRbs@QTBGQQl3JwLLtypMzEnJAnQTgQTy6vKgNSMFkkAfYDBM6iyMCO/RIj6hXGxKEvfAE01YSDm3nyUZkbyUu5b@mRi2LzN8eXH9eTm60R@NjXKfsdfdKiwDK3MgGRqYhigWGXPju/vHx3J0HK9RHwfV3Aq0B317hAElHWFDigZLXyFfdiLsw8xTRLVdgG6GmgfbT89NOoqNHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6BcL9Vd0I0CoEljCSUiYBVVuL/3Oaqlo9nBVp8iigJ5E7cqQBtzaQ8tc1XsgcDDcmtECXOlVUYL2qbCeJim2qSWo9rjnDpGDQsEhqhBI0Gk14Dl4PIImu1qnwPAMRFBcwdIHVFkaqCtgbX1KDqa@ANIg1B8JPX3rAXjYxUbqU2V4GizWX@rl5e/ghchLAM2jNWZruZoP5@rSNzHPhaIOfcz0mdvrKlvcI2uUPkc84UPdgwRUyH9lct75Na3oUFnQxZCU3FYEEClhDz91z7bZbCifODzoPJyCORZOch0TUkObu4IBqyTY0RDcGlMl4Zl4H2CYzpkQOleeTvt45KB9Rb/Y0k2GebghioWcsrtRjCRXjl9Ip0Kp2K0XRcOjTtE4fWe0JXOyOreZQIw9SjE@t6yr7pDem2FDXEgcfV1mHnjTp9uq2IQMse/oI6edCEui8LgxCpK0f0oLn1FTkvbyJZyrZj9Kf2gFYf0c2kV7fElMolitzvdMx1UYEIuC8seK6IBkwK27Mm52Q12MCNUzEwHgHj4trLouhX9x@xJbrD6DCBVP7zP3@jB/S/XjtDGChw5jF0tGHoxpqS@msry0@KL3RbXbF8gnxqmToRhly3gezqLhRJt0LHatC0CC9JMPyPcEnBr3Fom3gDqfGGZsYx5yuCwXN1JqsW1Wxgmd11ca/sx@JZ0fIPKHY9IgIXgkyDEhHr4pVgzPgSTETFRjZ2O1LBpilGjZnX@3A6mfI7CK63VqI5xt9NfdOPmcnrHdUA1VHvmMYNVe7qJ9OeI41PBqGcWlgRd1F6WgOWQBzwl4Pb6FxdfF5A1xzAOBs810VbDG3KGT1uaxWePfXGUoe08B5/o44wuiEH1@L3dVFM/0RU6FhPNdOi2zu2RB86NBR/N4SCe02lCNHMK2S29M4cZZDh@7eycGcBcJxaN5XKZNcsLY/H69OjJknpy@XVqWdyl9Nj1RyBwvezSnwWjQrs73C9pVZhuDJHuiVpvYhzLTNftTHhWtRwTZPSGKe4onO6suYW1McBqTu1dHfhuqGJL/AIlhHWzUj7w8ZTs@uAODBmalFWtWDoiAwYxDKDrXGLjHA7Md0i2x/MVWTsgVqIg7gUulazAKc7wS2ja9rUOzA0vlUTN8RGGonsrKNU1znD31rxYQiqKb@vHtFer8TqHZiTZHUtHcbxtcPB0uQgTj7e0lDPTM@g22rCnqxEdNK1Vvovd4Fg2i86jXdbs/ZMy/HYM7rfRKCBC1Tg99UNOkpLU7clmgyPum/gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2tT90@8n3/@a4cLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3VRCdAnNxf2vEecMQu4pN@Wsv60sHigEu3K0u2YNMiVLKCp/qW5MxLrmc6fPg@XMMHetIGwwd4zmJ0yDdYYJyCRwTl4vYP09uuZtz670bU7oGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR/VqVMi2jvmcKNZN5dxbVt6bG1FipaBx2vjTwrPINSsa7I5Xxi7Hpz9Tj4gAeTQljvfY1w3fCGsdpfLuRmeiW2TVuF2WWmdoYpO8xqs5PwfEUHddTDOzpeKlWl7Qz@@hmkg3HQZd2ekvYYcj78qHSLZLSknzuGfS7UWPiGh5uEKvlMpmML8BEVlyWXm7SpLJh2i9Nfl/KmHwWOS/i4iqbG3GuzoPIEt2CuJYFaesUe4pcLiu2aRuTOd7fkZt2HMd6n5oCptozURQDyZK22t5UY9fEHf8QCVtMXXg44dHpr5u04KONr1sCfVBpvqnSo0tC71SbEi56jnBBavn15umbyALTbbngYW6cE@Kbb631sqQ/G6LKJbl4Y6/jEqrTMSydP2aF3E3wynL2RnjLTMNfrMXFXb6ku1iKj11hSuM5EMvsgZYyNEYGvd4g5es9tDvgP9ZGmjn4Wxc8M4yuMts3uusijE3gCzbel9aQI8LSxLFBv5rgPj/UUyzcSer7ruPAwarfSiIfjPSBwQ1h3MQpFxMWuJuGq3UL5@qpiwrfQdOFZAsLB@ubBHSqE2PuBc@VAB/Pu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50Dfobev28J6fYi1h87QHhpDvm88fFvXOaA9TrjhkptQB6wHQ9zKNh4vbXGP0tNyLOtd6ImskTNKx@mvxGkfD7/iya33gjvXOxDgP26dvNMnnHegY22vGRpTGJc8Z@KMDYne1kW1cKKH39fx0GCR@uedQbpRzweKBM@fF/6tuuVAdybjMT3aY2vq0Y2SSnRm@Ta5qc@3ptCmSMcdyK@dUUf2PWV/3wotga9mMR1z0h3ioXHeso2B0@kOzduQ7hj6xDZPlGDKh7@@k@6KlDGZdB@9ZcsE8rpzGdtLLRr@DB8H6yrdnz3iw1rouEFeWTVDR8eypbF@0vX4bCi6WAUnhCO9kR/ertDx98qrqTlZAI3sZQqnd/myBDrW4e7vnlgrWdEZiQUb9ndVrG2lJKSjQC4ZGRB41HXZLu9zi3SxbJbf1iEULSVhFNmX8j7k9vf@0OygGZm3Bf@l9rW0aWnlIGcPpwPvOsPk0/U9ENHwtn7agvYyR6asYczSbf@xjsyapeAhR3i2QeaaGjeuqeRvXFSheKol6Y4JjzY8oOqma@fQLHPs8TuT@muX4vy9TKCLX10v5LSZr1am/YrpGX2@BIKu20TEkePiTmSQQaQurqTjDDoycy54ccZlOwNg6pLFFpGDuOvElpXbhFZXfzhmSp8/MQY67rV@ZE5ws@aKVkFNdtX2olthf22qe@bXplCydY0NLTbwZUg3erQf31bAe6wPzO7DpYoIkfQJ7O/05I@l5o9e1@vibGh6uKMpdNwwMYVNjjdibHVt0BtWxLw6bx8aq1h0IH4McmXsVXPrzniOp8Xm5LppWt2c0Cyr/1ynOq7bBHYjEmfT0Xjq@Y/VONCeqegs9OiE/L0zE4BLr4C1sqFuTVbPVEemXEEK8wfFhXOdNP6FaTkD9kUpw0BoAyEMhfMVDeceDM9PcUOOa69oiZT3Oy574kSH5PKCvYK6NbJMMm1zcvNszmSCm3OCJxaGjxx4QkF5hHf57vtCkI5XU@TR7bL@4mjyLeM7tLxnztTtGugM7Y1E1QI/V2Mv2H2MJzoctJdyFtXSuo4F3Qsc1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhwmalQqQZsMTX9h8/T0ZbA@3Wvk0KNUD5m3rWfOFau2HgSiMzbRDE1vPR5diBLnGf20k6oq3Ct6TZRWNOXWLX951V@s7TOQwg76wwAfOfju4bXVw2vDXvJ85jx3ZgNBoDoxwdGfzM/9JGj9UJMdkjPNUO9Ondms0zArtmEOLShj42OlC/1sL1LmMRB3xfn@hrhiKaGyT9L3Td2lZMq2O4X9KkX8S9TqVdRuihMSPdYn2D4X1QmnS7XCTG@bilPrK0YuONHcfmd@K2GXioj2/mKjAU0O3dF8pl3Ii/NC@wUj9bLurhKd8lYvS4UYp1ZXWNjmPx@w17kmyT7wnQXdPwlEdo44D8CjkmgfTl3chDijfykIVqBJLsqe7RIv1qVWMBUp29xxagoe52HVwJ8x037M6JGCa4hU2He/v5xoEOEH4GHEvvTn0LjLehZY06I7qtVRgitXlkdPBUUIeseUz02fXK5DNDvimDyI6u0ABAwK6wUxdY4iloI8nbh60lPWqZquaYbsSp1y6X02YdyTaN7msdZ80cotdibnopHMqsPCHnmrnqSDeiWWRFp5PuK3vS8tY1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclN09uBmZUV6yHTkYGLzMurMGtFV8cbUmGd1evpIXN1Dcm39Qe8JLT7x@VDaXet5Ing4f/w3scKDMLtQi4wPQKs6/YVfEB@6tr@411a4FPHm/TN2SHgjacA1rETLFYeksCD9wx0ba0rBNSePbX47MMgsu9q1CN1TCLTtpJkEbueGJJhn0pkCG52vUQOP/Sl7KJJ1InRk3w7CLjSID0Kzn@F0fznigXUKG/EzZ6qwgk7K@T87Z@riHsWcAaQt5yJNPboqYy9pwePDo/lsaeuHJ92h3g64poct2RYQStlIlNSX@puZL2Tb0frmd5EufdMlfYeHcgYYQ29@YqGBA9cmVt6rJ339O2N6oq@VgvCUGOyWkB8ePz4UWpxRJMl9oauMzKS0eC9Z8/SeNLk42crg6OpH0Dv6DuztckP9lU1uaL5PrdpdXAd91yR0zpIxwZoo9AYH3K7LLcKV11nbPSO52PjUxg8kYN775h9YW0hn@in5gB7ISuvJRR1VFaWC7lkZGc2KNuGGz7X1eeJOUZu2aWHwh9rt6Og5JBV3Oxq6eGmFf@rUgzL@DsR3i@RmrneWiemBD1jMESXont/X8RUVV1H52d6H@qV5ddW1nKEVevDlnP6DkvJhq@8SKGXNIFWJZm37iMvSiNg3QrecHre9wRnZ@02mJsAhN6FlR3@zLDnui3RWtZN4kUFUuOmthujfGG8w4JUuMPnFC1Ar1zjC7fUs0SXnMlbMj52I0n29u4d3JbgyKflzbE@evKcPdU9NEJyc8QoxsY7YLyQjL6UcN4KLeCtXU7tuQBKuxHeYLy6P1fYM93tOfZ8dvsiHJ1BxaGdjAuHsPCNIhmWOTNXjVVdPq/1dPU2o9vy5oc4nPmSHBw1TuMDevvtf6aqmQyZHsKnmuGvt9RM0MFZAl36HO3ZRYOOD0LW0EW5RQaP5Ept9JExw@0ofDZ4lVK/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Obwko3hOVuyO9aGHqyrJxRbwCYvyGM5eUw@JFjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVCN1UkPINBSlHuPPrUgYnQWlh0XevF/Hx6IL/WNlaj42JmxsPnY6ZW1mG3T4amWSP0Vj69XB/O4Xu0vaWgeMf@eDvq/M7mxorM3qsv14dQJzmZGUQMEFjOKUjEdeDlxdIOyDzGvbA5PYV2T1nsk9vNyhm4Ynn1XsRzPH96Xg9xsAb0c7/VXa@FPEz0JmdM4/dw6NxCzF9he6P@@NW@6@TaVk4MYhmRh8e7wat6/CZokVyXGDx@dMlbzw8Ojl8FvFzjdlsndIrzdbpkCtDFrk@Oc4tZbtdf3G6gljrzxuBuAH8OHyulYM4s/v42XWWgOrbcDKygpCPdXsxY7pUYT1nQicNVwY@nc9oG@XKmh7yXWyrwtzuCu8lxR4GZNOEvD2l3UbL@u32ulZ5bHxOaw8gBrEJF0s4UN/wkjHLDQMMKcnajuqcLISfBV78PObR1I7a8vbSvjUWfn6Znxr15MDgeiJhp1LJ5PInQ6JHYNHibWITLT5u0nFXiHtxwTb8I6YQIAaHVv1DtWgYDlReA0/FCgRiUtuEbGo1NV9mO/iNjgoItEnKEb3I/FaQV4NtnvvnRSsV9ZJt1JhYEZl/Yje0psstwgJctGUJZWLSico2JxCyGZw2ZfRxA3bBSEkGqVzNZ@BNVqLn7qv@eVxAafP86cHT/WfHu8fPnzUyrUv/vG5QCNuG3AKrAB9meyKU3ScbDL7cPjSdE7cgO/rwAirXXlAuBiW7UrTaUtEWhRJ3MM3muW0rCh1ZVqRLwE8SeW4Uik0IvDjsoMRUP/5p9Qo/PUyHoKGKOGiR8oQ6q7DMqozHOgwkm7YffvWDMhSKHxyq4CeHMGPfpC80xIHj9PwcPYPdfgU5Ptg9ePT8aJ8FCC4azZnZmwxr5Ty3@MzNKEA99U3aw1VjcT9JHOqqVos/iANh4nKcVeiQOVlbhnYO0QLq4PF0P/UWS2wSfKBgPKwU5T9/Q7mMy7gdOQlx4wFSccgWmjw1lI2NDXYMjYTdPzr4dP@IIf7798kbSYQg2DGecP2zH/f49woCCzTBx5bcEXF9suAhRE@5B0e/F6fTkebUdcfrP7lE3wegM@DhhwnCL6sIAn23AtrtGRmPu2JYLEm2fvgnony7b0FG1IQCG@c484023FyPnZqeiSfQEYc@mlRbbuy4WYbMCMpsF78nhV@t0unjGYD61J5ws0W@8ZIYtDQ5ZDlptknI8k9tiJGI8e0NaOwdAwQC5tkmDC@TCvsSWiLOLle4hQJJqsevJQlAV8gl4SASiXjNBpunNF3l7a/9E2VQZeCegPs7vnuWuQdvv@K/9cH9q9z9QsGGdt1m2wKXKEJoZ9EvAUckpD/SPvIZLZtbhVgQDk3LBXyVmSOoplOiOkbnOfC7BOx4ASfR@BQqDZob1JhvDYLnZ7itBBp6rCgKNikUUmXai2/M@Ma4KwYfC/lCTlUASek0AEgW2gd44pcDTCYr0E2EU3NcewmCz/b2NhNRUzVqhSqvWWXTfpEVX4aIbkJc4WyIyDUYpIEkixQQVveTweCTUpOYFLlXXI0j4@o5MCpROI5e@G77hBBZAojFaWSgye8ZfnFt4s4Dw6Ud/EZZ5Osdmz4gSYUxiVxJUfDtKDxxJtB8oJMuvs/D7SjgxlA@AqJFQI9/h5DshWJ7lK/3rMXx3@AzIX5fk5EHcFDZzNXBNFq34mcI4hmCqIirmm/jBWtOmnZL4W2TQTP94YrGbIP7l5XBmjbLy7173Vpk4qqtRyQWu/vMdlAlfwCFYQlN0bKKWkguipTLrSySXyI/GygOmqS5gOyATQHL6Brml87Y293bP/j48OmzaxYRKWb8ajTg@/XtVFOS041W6IhHi7VcJfceKM8e33sQVMQC6UKEGwPj90ui3lSSxUwbglyc3LhatFUYXi3deow/42e7r@Kb1W5CjRJdw0PNvEe@tHtaekBnoK5mrpVWUSufvwmlBTwlAnqPH2C9hmoieX7ZaG3Xm3Ysfr0lrOgIL2LyFnYCcDW9rU0FG/v1wmHBwi@EHuNnwrxoX8yu7oviZhYNbuH5@YlzsjBJ5ntEAiLlDbIBFinIShB1be875DL6wnCexr9gyi11Re0QRRAuZG6ieATUcfAxVOQiC7OfvsXLIahyltkRAvtP3PJlYKAvNHrJbTclkoL/8QieccL/POqsMpNpq1QiidyOYKXZTUY0A3hJATo0SndPp6DhPHXG3Jg4LYnfNwLXkQPsFxR8UqEN9vF0BPH69DgyaHkCOLcEiYGS8RBVLksBl/BtaM5SaKUU8mugJU2/4PKol0/MkvLQmPXMAfD2RDINHO1DVW2x0M4mFprsatpxkepsUQs3dsWP8FhylOzvZWx1tkBAb@gyqOjGLBE/iycrLcgf/eNnn53Gk@KqtkRGX30rqL2r1l9D9IvqzZxEn/i9MzCtuopblMvXuQT4XQXMrZAFXzIql@WhJ9CX6WoouT@buI/ACWJEoj/SxywxtbkFN5nRa6KZsNNk2kqqc@uQNkulSKGCBwXIjFL2ycXH74Ruz1lCqUEjQF/P7uHjtTlmDVWWW@CmTJJsE78wtgcSF9o0TAqgA0OSCoGtYRMCNQMw4p1E5g0c0mA4xIUH2cFbEUwfXKJZXAdpQqVm9Tss8sW4ZclRLJcrfoUuc8Uyg9Z3nR3KCoC9xucCuR6o6xt3AZqB@isLsQUjv87xYpRvjCPy0LcKA@jEIhZdA2MxDGAt7K12hy7@Evs29BWQDyqV58cP2qWkIrLQuszANXu4ysCNkocqnv8ZGeimylLUeJVrdB9hMrTj1@bma9Cc3APqMOIVlhqLkuHqR58XbVNVb2z1fkK/FiBmDgcA/xReOwCHtheDaaEVYauZ/c9@hp@VFhObqnrSdk9T8XymCje1mmd59uFmU5I2G5na3U0dtKjJq1kTdHJlK3f/1Bj2OwcDpSmKLMtyirJ1fh5/sPXUfKEVXs0us2rp1clYLTTkV7OWWKqlT1rs6dPP37TfJMXZ6fyV2Exo9HnjvcMLUc2hoh@rlNn5TiEbOynjV0KZrudP2Az0VnbCXsN10mf4T@7XvYhbR3en/5q@rhQXWazZxG9Ci0VRURrxFvyTuv8SLq74N@pyXd5pvXmTbOj6ZDZnpmmOvV4Pfs4QJEgt@YxBvneA01N8hTXpSQoUXaNZfzGPoOfhVtfwSKZ8t40@ZBJytmsMBtN9fW5OH0wef/FZcD3H6/XRigmJViqVkKTGVe9KW8/HmJbR/uwnG5fp86ft7T/75kgxNvBxiI/vXD5G9zM1/@HGxof37uVyaU3TuPvpF0@/vru7m7ufzj9t5HdyUmZj@0//ZGND07Y1ZaPleWor3jg5@VzUMjlR/rMfxdtPn37N8@rZ//Mbb@oq3opwO2VF4BNwZZkKTryX4KeijPWuV@x1DFq5GpvTXzsW@J9vMLW@U/wv3zt8FZvE6prymQvPSexVrFCKcSc44C0bvJ3G6rFtjFa4jM2VWq0GzuJ/@beQvv4xwMGQ@Tbc6vkAVmEeq0s1SnIRqxfAoWoa5Pt/f@MbEQw5m6iRGBdcd1kDLjFX1MSdFlxbdG0LaLVPyihKEM@eDCeGw9TSHfUOvpjwAg/bQPPnxqQZw2/ussO7jB01UqlUS25LcMkvcI5IUVWtqap3gBtIH27VatIW42YJs9n8HTStnKQZrYEDA6Zxh332D3HFVnlWf25wR0KssHH35f16HQqVrWe36im6/J5EnapYEh3nrsjS7GUcVJBG6@Uj3nNYXcyUNDGdTvPuNENSSbNFS8KL32Ox0Ae7LLvqt5QEovi@sfePF9vH68//tz///p9/j/6@T7//gGYN7Z7ZV7Yg0il0iTpcdyuVbr0u1l3xvInvdWhHmUqpUlLal83EFnCg1hFTMx9dxPPZ@DOG7B8GANZMUmq4KNu6nz2@12ML7zr3qUf9/AAemTyYXwpyLFGN3CHVrsWDodXfACo1TustCQWimtRQC/mWxFMFWNbLrHEXqknUimWxVdfy2iFUnSryihtuesyJgWZYCOjo41tflK0ehize6lGvWD1IVl/Eed94Abp1IdZoKC2DBoTAj93dqGyUKoWKprRDz@sXq173MgzjqRc7jYUXp05sQdBY2DSv@gVVEb6woAWz94kHklGEg83CK@K8erVnN140vw/XBvzRP1zhK943yMf3pijXrw1WUbe0rJL/sLCvsfe7BBgnWLfT6bzudlAM0Dt6V1cn@lSf6XN90pl2ZqzDQIpiU/hhv5GlWDavbsbusLVFEmJvGhvsiHOhFksFVzN16/Vcltu@kxwO/iTJmcWE2D/AVVc1lW3B@JSBGwhl5ASdGf9UVWCxc7hab7Yab7agg9ZT28QdW3XJxxIecvtuKyVdXjbAXa36/9v10Fmli7ugcK3LVGr7RR1Ejxf1RgpAvvBByhIjoHK73tqmkDAzPzc/eLsFwouU2m5s15w9@kESuKR4zokXnLstALy9hOzduykZXHcBQH0T@mMyldqUpA0cGxv@WAGRW/VUUCrEIQHSwvn5z/kDRQ@67OX2Zf2ysX15ub0N/9t0v/Sf4Hu5fe2fHotrTZxFeAtZS7Oh1JtK02cULXiXlTr6yEoTHHV4QrxGViu1GuiAS279t/kvpxf30AdRbsmAtRDbYlsxNLKXjW0JsZdvv/pf8Nd8@9Xvo7zI4M@oCLFz7NbKFmqbZa50wo3Zj232mF82uPEXvKIPejyuo6fNbzYuSCnKS5lV@Jx/Qi0VkjIOwG2n38Zz@zJ7CVFRcINxiYlaqSC2U@pcY7FtsVCkkekXr13xePwfvdTKxTifnsHj5i89z3scwW2BHUSuahlVUi/q3KI6//jFL666/tEvrruE2EWZGRWgStdjnB5CDJpPTJJglKpvj3A7Mq6PSKiKntY@l57vSjh3ok9o9avL5wVqB/u1crnOl3Y2n1JX2bq/BXcV/vc3oBSs2Ye4zX6tOwKpt9nP5rUmWt@OSZ1X@PfoNf6x4y7@Hb3CP3b8Gv@OJvjHHnfw7/gV/u128O94hH/3XuHf49f493yAf81fyGbVqrh5ToRJqWX1cnMmEoGqsZ168xcm7rxiGXbD7LX8D8tkc2WWjDV/wZjh58Ur3LMf/@l3v/nNeK0Wl@L0uY6c6rhMTVaB9lAiL169GxdiNbapbqoZK9PNqB21Aw6TZVyWGWaGag@Uk7bKMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9cBvxlwGVm@iwzYBk7Y0NECAXXpJ2ZoKsPjwH89QGQC38m7q7rqJkug4wsFNToS38IHlwX7abQYHEmvjRAv5RVOSMXzBZ@H6UhvnzZVLZaWrnEZGxScrvxshlvocFsrZxjnbmx0XzZZjEPNNRqTGk2FU4TKC6R7PKy3d5/cr/dVnCcaT52Dhf/h4ej6OuN/6ND5/GhM3Lg//DwEPqGUU/dTQEHvnu3BhzZf@zE6tWdZoX4esDbY8r2TrOeldBdSAG71tAv9Z7XAiI86xtNIX6WQOXiDPWL6mdn1dMquc@CV3C0q4sIQTTu8J9wncEYFugbZ3CdnqGD3tB59lkzdHGH8tkZeH3GQLMK/0GDi77@V/g3/9v6f/ycJVmi0Uomzi@3E3Ql8S@ZPL88v/Tv9WQi4b8ktuEPPeAdk5xf1tFJkc7B1UgkW8nLS@4H90RymwOsQzbbdUq7iAd8PxZmSdnyW@K/7hOy9q9mvMqA45D2nM9QP4qJVaYvNs40m7NMJlntBLb/cRlYv6DdCckqffhts9NQW3/6I/q@w06SIuVz1aq6xfiLltOq1VzwVixVq6XgZTORKF@/6pkdtQAKRi6XTFar8LITgM3AK6RtsDcpVmNNuLfu3OGZlLSLC78ckHmQQR5yMzy96zPV84ND@iICcJR8DD9FwjlIIkPfU8FvdsXFinjnTsL/FvjObvLOHa2cubgIfcZj8FKXvNrtnum22@ifvbgQ2yLtbynn4T1TurhQM@WUGk86buIJfuwNskpIKvtQq1OuZWDVWq4IwT4C@e3tQq5eL@TAp1CKJ3GtvIHotwDfuBivirFzKoNaKnLGJ1bR@x2nlRh0bxwU2PlljOqY5fLJBHDXJMh9lzH8495qucz9kyxXSJRSZf@vtgFqN0gx/A9FsWwqt1XcugtCLf6t1imQJ1fPjZp6WTs3Kjhtflnt@t/PRfMCxp072TLQqpSpNoV2@/7u8W67XRNFESUhuKEncXcBrS648QaRIF9ucdJUqnepvtVSnkHF8jhSHEYIVgLqK9pWXi0htQSzj9ZDoPyCSgTZYBuCRk@8CWVOpg3wBH0FMu/BxXqgQQ3wYgOc/WQms@hiFuPhdO92w0gOv/zQ8JXS4hX6GOEl@K03y9sqjNhPH@3u7R@ntW2JxbQHu3tp7dnzezEVX/OLdwrO4vvR/u79w@eQ4Omj/d1n@x8dfLr//Cn4e@xscQVM378vnlHXivcz9pnwpftaNwzdmBpG@2w6PXvFvjTNtgmVaU2hUM7AZZ7RhrKM9UW5qvDrmp7@5Ze6O6aLvf3ht9/@8L97@zvfffs73377O9//6Vff/zb8fgy/7/Lnd/9NOY/3n371z3737W//Dnj@B/j9Efx@8tOvfuMb/Efvfwy//xTx@2P/F4nHfwLA@pWffvW9H/30q1/9Afz@pf/7wfXfr/1k9e/731r/w3Tf@92b43z338Lv9zisIO53f5v74fNa/N/m8X71B2//xb/j/3/q/6Hzd97@iz/Gm//yT3/wp//p7Tf/vaaV/vRfv/3W995@65tvv/Wdt9/6x9rb3/jXaiZ6@9233/@Dv/rD3/urP/wf6f/HdP@9d/l/@4N/@hf/61/873/xh/7vJ/D7d@D6yV/8e@gqf/sHP8T/7/3B3/7RD/H/f/5Xf/sHv/63v/I/keM3ueP/@Zf/ht//@tf@49/81nf@6iff@Jtf/8nf/OYf/NX/8av/12/8x7/@73//r//JN9HzN3/yV3/0K3/5zW//5bf@@V9@86s192/feP/qHfy/@gfweXc83wXOu5TrfX2@@rnw@ftQY5ELtBNo3b/89jd@CRr4v2Ds7bd/jAdz4Lfm/8eaSnF@zN/@P@DQrpcZQzLggt@vv/32d5FE/wOQCP5Den0nfFkK4S/fWbwAWX9rRaJf/ulX//xH9BYzKnValsGxu6SVUlug32yVy/747a/YQJJfWoYWAvBz@g5yqKWw7yBve/vDb7z90T9@@8PffPvDX8HBW8qV07tpSb1FLoGI@XeIhxEL7xIPI36O@adoDk1KfQ5v7HM/8PPPPxfaFwqeALt7Ab6fkxe/GA/CE2J@UBCG/nhkjF2wqNt3Znznpu8b5sxY4@XLFi6ogh/mniLZYysQjfJZNksFU9JsFkxNY6TZFp@lxjv5YvBMwNvif@GcCSy1mMzGL9aFU7qUE4/mZ8GdQh6ySc1mkTlxknsIQ@5DC8GUb67MsASzWWoGSjA4IIcUBN0DcbxWS2HCGscHXjlq9RIjVFKpGpQbU/M06XYJQczuERRIWUsdsfZWbcYTphBePSBHSkCvI1HVxFSpdh8yrM3uM4SFwAnsy5e1eqk2qyO4N5weqVnqHuGEwGqpWf0NvNcIJqQTYvffACqlWipVL2GGWEhePek2r6Q8FY7KnmIpvw7gifv5d@4y9qGolsQ2FxiRYDw23lOL2BgRokN4M7XlF4f@Ayf9tojgG5SVnwvj4Tskm@5wcRUjAFxJkmWZwQ9X2HfYXQiecVApyhYeKQ4hRS2CWkDowXAyKCWkqH5T9AL5x2pb730hMCzM5uamEKuLWfFQJtIpCnNPKnS4Aff7oZJVYWKhLKK3QSc9AlwgfZXy34zjylmcccDswxT/3b27xT6EYtJz4ScwKZV1ck6MQ9lOpUQN4NedlPAC1BIB2ikBuhDkWY1W6lJCOs2YXIthGDs8PPSRII8XNSEFzVzLqviO60XT6TQGKWQ5LafT/lOmJ3nIvkOmUP8pbyJx6bPITNNyVdCeqgy9WFTVUUEFRs83b95ArdAGqsoBaKHM30ul5UoUCB7cEIZlzYMTQVquLHDNnKmFHGMJmk2FK8mSAkuwraTAt91zJIIrEddKpTjFA@rLia1ga11BpeaAM6mxOiIaXHxmsZRPBoF7h2zv8PHj/SfH41aLCQZ95tloj12na3heAsN2n9znRy60ciEZazQQ9HFFQwYj7FcyxIwP7h8dPKswXmi/ChKEWJUWTv1illUhNh5/th3ztxaJ@KUyR3yG98qibAmtnIWksboQ6xqoWeCKeJW2lFSFx97gnjMD5T4timm1gJpdkuaPmfB1Z8rQjiY3ugF9Cg9iyNvbRAGhfi7R2gQ6obYKQr3ub8pjqlB/tn8MCY4PmaplZKH@OZvJmKF0KdStmmXYg8lwE3e3ic2MGCnTZiOTxj8tm4W7miuk1XyxtbFhnUuYZ5Oq7Ry3KV7C67mExfgALiZ8ILAPwAsuyAP3HjJ/4@fBYdXffYcWqxJ8C56o5qGbJQWctObghPHiAkShdS@v9AixjS@@mLB6HfRr6eCBEANuMWTBBjTJ7MlDmaq5N3UNCh0w1jM/NfETdHLP9MaWPoeuA9SIXV5e9gHSwQOm1TV65Sl6eL/skk8H3JczXYjZlUrtjZorCtpJpfImq2kCeAhbCu5w24AGQBsFthT@V/Ugk2y2pACnUkURHtlsVsCJYkGoGAKj3SBvMrWaxNtgNqfSZhABv2qgz2paePlxZx8u4mYzPC6GQAAbTFyWCcKKPMx/Kwj0BkTD7W/0Dd2q3zkzd@5kcRIjm8uEsxVUYnYJdbOZzWWR4sL/f0UvWsHZHtezGXVbGYNTB2duW9HB2QFnflvpgNMEZ3lbMcE5rWfVzLYyrQtM2OamKxlaxqiJE2OGlnK5n1j3DKsv4xmimkgZaOK2bwq6HiSs92o9p0vfwa72ZBO/R47nWHmCXE6sOjYaVauheQU6@csSyXNhUDuj07aCURvIaKfDtXVL6MkdpzeXvcncwtM4luPW4iAVxoOABXQDxBGcAtvJZnOVBmvJY2e8I2j5YqqhZmAcwZ9aSmvpDWOnWKz05K5l6O5OvpIvpXt40Mdf1trJZyoD@fPHjx5OJuMjg07/7OTKkAAtW6ENmp1SJZ9vNRqimGpQNi38ii/nUtLGBnRtQ@9J8MRFL0/SSi1I3DPdWi0e38mqmqRWspnSpbAgHNIcS1gXMGkKS5ZGup/7jKBiOzbwnEpaT5vnRIVKv9@/3DpPLV4E/Vzib0CfS0lPd87D16oUiVdh07RkLgLBR@8Duc/99byKqOVLYrVRXbwXC2K1dSncHRk9U8dDP83M@fVUBeDNHGoMMmoy4bLiOs6k0jH6jmssImbVQhCRI3Q9Qk68DLNrZjDH8@vZFSKRZufXoeTy4mWYKkBLuLwEunNiQ7/gZknrtDe2oZZzrX1gRI3WdmCwFOsm9uKFrtfrUMnnuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1GHDKuUK@BN0sU8jkNQ0A5MqlcvESWrQQ03WpXstqWUHTJC0rZVVJzeL/LQ4N/989vgb/Gt4hVVYTjtHqxxMYyWD0tdkjtB4wcdixg9@PGbB7RndNjL2hTruI91zH8/4ece7p9gkPum9yU5th0EMdP6LljczJcE2M5@MRGgwx3H8wCPujDiCIrIlHuAc313KcVRGK7PnTNaV8HBq3BmJw69YQ/ejgo4fHkefx/u7eQ6HA7h0@uX/lkfcj5dmj/QfH4WuRhwZJ8yGIr@8/enT11X/kDp8f9aeOiz/hweHz3OIWeuEhVSEH13Kk0JuA@Dd8JVkPBnnQjfLFwKEKeLThDuird3xnvrBwZtD5GT@Ba3rhVnt@GLsiHAfHcnWGXK9jsC63C4MKNNls88VrtVgWhDGznTNWzLCeY1k6fhG8vwGeQx2PGBooY1r0QXvM@sxxrd6Z2TM2hMd4mrGs4teXEQnhIQAZTbtkIwDkC7QA2sNvdeOSUceaGmw6Zms94YFe6HTNwRDGwzMniCB0dJ3B730vSG9Er8nNHhOeB/ldC7GuRxdigijuieJDfaLP7sZKjarXGtczlcqdO@pTVyxnRRggdW9g7M@g3bLn0I90d54uiRNZfMDkdmyA6w1WQc0547peB/2gAdJ0WYPhdCenGfVSJp/969/68d/9ya8PaupWM7OX2d55/ChfASYJEiYjIdIXNGVSObRyKV8qZ7VSulQu5fJqIZ9Pq1oatLViGQT2jFpSC6V8WU2XcmUQDXJlCM2Xi76YqgRyqbJVAbB2Fz8LvE1aizwE9YSvFbLXCT3JYnr4PmWiAWlEARXECZ3b3jJrMKoxNcOyRQYQddZlsQcP9jIPHojiPXzB/RR7GVHs4Uu@lMkU74miQSF7JRRzRIenKaGBNXHCXzKZe0DuKQeAtslFcYgv@wWc6hJFE1/2dh88wHz6@KJheoh2wkP4ixW8FCGajS8gPROAVyE0iLbL88kRovv4glliyAMesgdhovhRgA6GHPFoHMDDoKS7u6J4wF92dzFkj4qd54h@gi@7dImiCy/QB0RxAI6BC71PFDvgxJ4gil1wdec6@OEnmNF8tT3RRXHOyYMEEsUZxda7J6LYDvwxm099bPJI3Qq9qLzUd@mljH@iqAVIY7Rs@JIVxVz4koOyPXz4qT6c9IwBv@Yuf3ahpA8fZnVzNt1/0Pnoo85g0HHnu/sfHWHQ3t5DEBHmU7cz6PgJO224HEi191DTT0bzqxeU@qDdrujWyqBP2u2cbl8Jas/bBmIIqV4BZv41wIxG7T0I2nvYvquvWuIlgG1kAiN4dvC6N4LnPb3Dg4KLgug563TEKjZ/RWkmBBTicXEWu@MJMFU7PdK7rlPF91mNZdKo8s8bhUyrSgFsBMJ4pnqJ4f0E3nWcl0mezxuzWqZVm9WKGt8j1E@IzZmWN8X0xmhHLecrG/qOquVSswqajnD6cRaX1B2WUO9svWaJJ8kdDQRzsbmzI4kNtbWjqaVKofhiayqKyQred7LFCkTMxDOM4S3ZKLZ2ivlIkmIxpStapVhMVi@BKBMY2js4X9JOJM4M/SSZRHRRe4ciUFnZnMppVvuJWXpW43ixebI6q6lVbraVZa7B6qGN8Gl34rgc4gDAzXYyFVwdT4hquSRC/oqSSCZDpge6tLDYf/nZ145Pjo8/hzAm1P15haf8o@ZV//Wjh3vywWHwhta95QeoDjmuvIdcaymEG58OvI5BMZAfwmgKSlbgh0f0XMeS92kLG@hUQUBgs1X2LW3Kxw@X4DwbOmc8Z7RwUCVzbXbXYGj83OwxvVYHl95jCcKK6ckzGsfb9XqtXRuREQAoYpDqE0aWwRdgDjyOe2h3gZKf47E1P6Bdy1xWO7VZbAZw2jUmqS9HTu@llupWe2jz/F7tHiautuHZqRo1w3UdV4yJ1f6OXWNsant633hquGhR5OBwE6QKPMuW6DMjucma@xh7D9WHS6nuMnuB2ZPpKAHyeSe57BV5RdIkvhYU@ZwOV@Luictqv8YSL5LVV/DqbrJET76X3MlVe4l7rJ0En8zL/ss@01ghV6WPEScQEnQjog2WWU/W6p@AIMQBn1QqgIhfxycAE3MCsGaPAvTk2LysdmsWS0hsxpJEnlx1UGtg6gu8bUui2JKkxkVLqEvSZ0Idemp1HtNr3rRDH8pgmY6qZQrVGfipxVx1CBWrv5hV3dp46hpVC179STZ@hlSvAjmBagDm9UXi7S99I7kt5Wvcr0qgLiyQPdpyuzar2mh6D5pELVuDgFQjl0mDSg23YhpGe62QVgvpbDqXloroC0N9Op8GT1BzQLZIWAmRMTGdmWVkNa0aajqReWn2XibTJwmQW4hkLJmeOPv2dMTAByoJWyW9wlNnyZS2ZTGoBYfp2xI1U@AVVSwY0HzIxmZ6iKCODN2iFMmkxLJbCWszgXE2j6fj/UarUtmfjb8GQQnp1U4hVcykXieT1cRGsuYZr4R6VagjX6FSjzegzfrzj8ybjhpQx@BSi1ql0ehgEYuZdDaThdKZ7YvBtlgXW@nMRkGFKrpkxDAY5xjRKTmUdRZ@4zaK35YBVaeWtaog0/xYtqRJZSW/lc/wOTqeUhj7jA0pyRJNMTgvnYjHi1o8noxXcXVgQ/Sng4GbESeLA1uN31F3RBDDxIpY1jDCginSkdhMgB0IYpcCzkawXFmInQuX55fboBsrtLESBEe2QS5Jrt8VYhXGgDE2fQtNygZj77tfM7Vdf8GfTdyJD3AFspELgijtozJM1MfYp3j6f4fFATHdHTU0LdtqaEUYyoA5BlFBK6/igkgM9/rLdaCwdw74bafqeHDuEzaf6ykpmKG/w9ggtSlQmWNXFz93a7uDo91gT9juHk76NkHgxq1isfN4LH4Jf0LsLp3W0/hpPRaLnNfjk/6/EL8bi8fjOLsOhHoTIx7B9s6D6bAKfrItoVc4R2i0km@emNZ5KSvxWQpgUZeXsU0Flz79VYtsrpAsU00Fp6Y@ealBI4nZTuABihJOKMHwlc/jTHZMeTn2vtBK2ccHh/Z994HB@CGqUq4t1mMso0p4Fqla8X3zYnvjRIU2khWzJ@kYuxujHe1iuaSJGveoxtiJFFcr/ODV@Fn5RfFF6cXj54fPDx8IsebGxYaDixYs3FP3xv74axAxns3FGWvWYrNazt@QrdbrkrqtoZG0IqsA@@@rBSlzUefNvE4BBQ1C3v7SD3Kz7RK8axkV3jUtn9LqdXVLY8nY@O1Xv4/2bs73P919xOI41f13f/Ijrfh3f/KvaDdY/JKmv7VsMQYx0akWirHz8/H5@SVcPCwfa8U4UrliEtx8KUaN1RVVy9q2XWUVRde3iqmcdteuKn5ctagmY54U8xeVivmYd@EHaZkSBAWrPuQlFrBKYvtHZl5T727vQHF2sjmtugHNSA0PfbLwb9vwyjEhVnr88oIxeOnWe4OBqZFLUVjljcS230jb7A2uuLyRNtjLWh1X7lU8KhqsSGzh0TlclYvXU8pWnIF2xOqNy@plK0WLGqBOvjCMLbt5pRM0N/DsxLLXlg1/xpZHf5go8PDgNXgztr70xMRWUlF6vdCo2rbB8nVoFVsK4LYVLEvwP0lqJt/@0m9oWuHv/uTXLtoX7c810CfL5YKqxX72s@2pPfWMXv1nkPAGQyaBTkhrOmhxBB2hLsm4cVDTTxU65C6osVMb5WYeP9AsUZdEmcMc2EaPNEvhFOUkqsg2t6XXS1C0LbRzkCa5m2xXJauCEMqnJFe7g26aYLAtNBoJPV04Fz7AIBiMGcjmVeGDBSjwGMHw63TbnjV1x3TSJEHp1Faa3YEkkMMHaKZwg@wz@JxcAu6nbF1PylH2iGokU7GR4Xlo9BAGIeEDSOJb1rXmbKyjKRGMadowdMgYhfCkgF4D8m5B3hZP0CbfBJWeR0gzjh1PZIPsLXwAwgRRwQQZg5nbEKEKbOkDIACUIeEDNltsm2WT7NxMpaoLi4qXuGUebT7qgRkDAZMhtB6azQgSVzEeeIHMj99yxHbh1zCIdxHPAAiHwVfYa6A1YHJ6Q6GN7Iy8MyiARTa9ElQ0dufOAqtazewlGZUI4Z@YY5z8onqwV@MKwAKN68NeRUwztFVZDXzDZgcUTxG60OokbqSyGknKRHy9FAT4f@dGiy3ySlVRQBUL4NcX7xVdIBkkRrLzOuyy7RpTtWKShch3AfcuIUWnyUM1sjn7UNY@DwIvAcOfxYIvpQCLOo5OKPrt9qodCwaD6BQ/U4HWzDgz8O1PcHtlyOoOJkHqMBUUxbQodt90QcGhpf/AVGIiqyYx2cK0JOFBu9u1HMNN5vkkPigVxmbw1NHkn5/PBpkq6jpQod7YsclGINkwwo390CKAR/nm1TjaU/sMP2vk1w0ljmLkkWk1bPmIMdk8pO9BU1pce@@4oAcHtEkzYyCz7qjHtDJLUEMjM3B2CC5JiQjhDkjLSOOOZYwApWeGQUe/vIqiDEDYmnbIFt5jE9rV8IEJ443tKf6nt5Uz88RUjvGzDJLTxxNi3LJIDOUz7H58md@3O2c5zgmzzBODzxMnluyyeAz0BRB500DZxQ8IW8H9I1o2jRMWaprHgl8RHkXuLKUjaTcS8@T1Z1bdSLSxRi9o8DFd/Kz2qW5H6EvXheCryN7cCyw7kX0ieJdDlmv4Nl1qcbTWEBorEnwbVTUyjyTj@sM4AQprYNsJncLYNU4ZKrsCjjHANLuBlRTsxVDaD2gAoL4HPQtNPk7cCtr2AUzcXqILXc9n8Db7kGU1ASNyw1u@kSyAgVVfW4YOYZAUy@FNelAxMk26I1@B3jnqQRhalfCbH6YPWje6yRznonmzDR8cDjqUV43xbhG85CMv2DuwPVPRNyCwABiuwGQjIaYAbEpMihx0mP5qct7aBeIlFXYdUpohBJ/UAIVEBR1ZDn0FffH9IQEC7ukeN1LvG4Q8OzuTyUrp1DVlw8Nv8niOrVvKeGCCRO0oE2M09r9@auJXr324C5fEP8Ulj4fjnRmKrrXynTl/CkLfq/m7cBLxvhfHwfEUPzkzGJFFMzQl5lGDemDS56q6CX9TEG9/Wit9HrS/CrY/qRS/RCCMIZhZep7upgFYutM9SffPelU/4JQ6JACHWjQCT7Qd7AYvIy9wmeN@GMOZIB8NgzrWCa2oAiSRz@wusuYlDGLOg1f/fWzOIJFtnLFd19XnCQpPYmxswIk5iT1sDsM@hYAThhl2zg3ZmrPGvLWUfBYmh0Et3E/gorky4fxmoNyqMYbPePgMwmc8fLbINMi2MWtxkQy9LrE42OrRymUQE8HMgziX3ALwIoQgg/TNVA4CY86X/C7h161R6oDe/A3qsRY0DGgTYyC4kVAaL5qNZsv2jLOtVkoZQGMXiRBQ4wC60SKanvVCN1LfOrXGjrfkZaNxUxiVfLzRqzv0WwNvK1jGsIKoYXB6mWiPcjDyNz5wgcAvMEBAOQwCUTTYnSTMZDW0ok2B0HAa4oLGHLGGj0yLpC8/yPcDcYmTnhM2CqgVAYT@YZEATQhhQc/hX2ALuMNnrgNxgrgSfTRqhHbR4q04UPJKV@G8pkqVFMFKkgI0gewortauFiUIh6poXAmKFPPSr/8o@hvvjX4f@sVq7KnB8gGjKkS7Cm45BBHC7y5EVVavReoVMFC2dMtwYeTa5/KpP1pDNltKoGbwfLAI3hl@Vj4RqfxuktcPHWwUbbESNoV5rQZFnNd4t@T9IiApJ3iYzPOTzYOG4KfnDARgZFYmM/xks2iyWa3GGQebrUl2FkFyRkjOeBIee7YGyZafDLSng2B4weppgXSKeyJFgKfyYRTEoLHI8NvyuCT@JdpsxNUEP88Fz6FW4LchFLGxnXVbK3NvRJCOMK0rALAhXgPQ4x9zrQhXGZ4qhW8hj@KkDHgUf/ObAecV0MCIBVe5XeNE2MhIBwaBX0zROAB9V0w1BFGleWH8y/CfmA48g5963TOzHFNd9sykr/z9g3i2kLKRDhqRPtRMDhkyajLPbd8gaFTmiOF3z4cOSHWdM4clVgjb4K9M/aRKx3I6ykjHrS34iUfuK4/nyUB/wDUVdnfsTPSJk8tVuNJkUrNblT/XGcyB7eCXYSK2zUHW6zmGZ8cnUKldZ2CbnpFmaHbyxPDVDsP/2IIQlZN9p@MJgj@jydVYBM3bFYq67TZ@dLrdTuA@wmQl3BtN2wqxecbjAuq/4IqkB/bkAz0cJ5zOl0Z3krwdJhrq95Mdm92TxOHYD8TZ110GPKwL8j@EDkGCYZ6z0BzJCDiK0p1Jgr6KMnRGzgCkvqknC5j6CviDBWxESB@PCZc001GlrUQ@10C9JNFN60k/6SfvnZR9oiX0ZJheWwawRIw0c6/SGCnrrsiuvTY7nizI79n74/ssiu@zm/ElLfwqzlw1r/HA98s6m1hAgIgLNLK3o4FFB77Vu4bOEiqhN8pVPME7o9ijrWM9xHQXou760eU@tI90@ObBW4j4p@vof3MFBsn337X6dOj27Nkc@M0It0Qm6GNeXrA4moDoB0nkPdezC5v2/XfMC@LidxQfoAgBYiwxLhvtF0PHHIPa7YXTxQHgW9o87ta61u5pC1eNB67AyT1NsxNtfRXdb/cMS58bvYQfMx2BG5T4CBQ24lfvVnBkdMT0HK7rJWDsSoahMIwj0Xmkypomo6dPk8n1zYpHMcPWQzPlhOHBevph@DXWjFN8NT5bDXpAPB7D6dhTE6c/x/PxnJvIt/iXnHw@yscfXpNopeF2ggAd@OipphfZJm9in0eJsEjvMCKEceXlIqMF6wAiGji6XofvR6LbSwqVG0lUC2pZWP44zOoaN2@q8UirCNokX2V6tyZ5W6N75zYXaWoc2IKF7b3fEHINMu7n6HYTUYjc58Yac@xrPAH9aJ7OXjOqtFcw1DAlcbqJSeo2yRdJATXjA3jihNOn8ESAA2PS5g0qKBvOafkfR2QUMtLHEanF9wEhHaBEqMhJ7qMRiSUEboh@fhnm2V2bZ/dant2lPMMesJxlJJLQXcrSrwWsnpuqwDL6kzXcGYNQd4bHTWwbLtvRXZytOI@b8YqZZvHTeAUYctyIV/YTwJTjvXjlPjm8eOUZOU7ilU/Asehb8Yt4JegWGMGFV3LcRX@fheN7N17ZSyQvhYl@YnhBvnK8EtYpxNnhr0QRIAWWG6RGXGKzHb@YE9eAgY2EyjTDFuOlUX2ieZg0/TLwzz/3RB@CwUCc49yiyCzF1KVBIzJi8Hxg2Ag@NLCiJ1f80Xz/8AHthwqjYDYp0PGiaQg8iOGx@DIz4ohhKK1owBMQRL5ZWY0Ri4xk74iOnzu0UKrk5fyJejLJA70EhTcgcmuRCX3jy08f1NcyCF6B74YnJl6H5zV0guwII1yTTa5AC4n6Mn5DobCul3Hxaz9aQzTXvRwJsJWCKLyWCGyEp4MMR4tzmNnYGS83EgrFDfhmNA1NyvFOia33SjLiCn7PXBNM3n7JkDFEO3/ypuJE0iFqSywIAxuZFu9l4bhAvBiDFrwuIqnyzgcoRHgO9HCje0LfT7vvOykeZzdpGivWDUNBWp4lca5lNgmJZbQ6NdUnPPdQed1HW1Tvp74GKWc415JAAJGUYS6cvzrvIb87XH4PBOqACFcyWCVYrx5Kr4vXN46yVzC3Ftler0AMTLP7yZXCUZjDguSgHUQk85va2jURH7d8cCGfZxpCvyLtB2QLdYJb6HZVt@CwUEpwT5c9TzTwPNHWE@q6RGKdyoHQImNOPhxe8BDTRdFuxpUXfFUVYwjNb@vWe1ewu1zB0cpDeFQA9wrJeS93pzbtcln0bWDb3AdZqlphnJHTcmlYzQtPYPe0dBsu24LHYfvo/uGTR1@HQbdYLCb9MXq@wA97Lc61huM4h0ybq8PxYIXaoqXxI0e42I3T8d7Q@X@7@9atNpIl3d/UU6Ql3KhMqSRhgzFC2AKErb0xeLjY7QNYXUglULdurRIG@dJrZn6cFzjzfx7hvMq8w/w6T7FPfBGZVVlCYHf3PmfPml6rTakqMzIyMjIyMjMuo/GD037mliwRYU3KQECtGPbTc9zVssyS51Nzl@pJWYuiGtYvyTQIUlIJqk6AJbuj6TomgoTj3KNAAzHqLdHb492ay@l8Go1@0AsbDV6@TGJXvYphaMyNuPu37IPCVTTi5MqSi@racTjqg9reV@9eVY/U0aua2jne@qt6v3@s3lX3juDw/@Z4c7e@pej/2t5hTTkpq0vk7cOGkui6HTZDJGNVS8XiE8WQtwbDicid3JYr7w@Dnno1aIa4plqPgt6LS/nh98PxhtSq0XZ0gjPMDudp7HXGsLfgxIK0jYVy02KnQXgDKCp7TnvaHva8vUGr0@5QWQd732EnjIyfmep2aARJ3hq3Z0@UJOQQZNMhzg0KC6xrqh5QedzdEJhA7K9AYpSQpIMtX2nCxf/9bgoe1Q5eHyrEjtja39uuH9X39w7Vzv4B/Xzzvr73kuhZPzw6qG8e4xMXfL2/Xd@pb1X5hSBQ9BWCOvx8FY3vRcFHcaZK8xfcfPtDGv74V/rUGxq8ug7YfTJSC1d9SJ9O0O18ClsLZecqgvoCl02@KlC5@erBy7e05qvwV9xwmqtgtj/IHEec13K@qNa5NZosGzTfynq60rKXL7l8H9GbKKS2Ccsc7CHHz54ywNmIp9UJVWYLNio4@5aYEDyXDWhq6AHBBihjsFJRnJJqYcFbZ5Ab1FqzO0AAT2lNjAj1D1R9YUxNyg5TTNvKACj8Hep9nAeVyvEL4nt6saSbHY@kgHocv5AC6om8gCpah@2IWtYlrsb7VxDPakVe/Nwb7vC1sHoav9gMeBe7qnGSceMhDVSc0g8RMrqceExOeTg5Kmd95ioRl0dSrm5XJkYo6SBJJspVItu2UckMCZs2rhq02ZtkWcZX4gbYCQXtcaRyFddXRzAOCvsdSfl20Q36YgKVmO4w76lVBCOqbGj1IU6Vxh4kwwEzINI0pvGI621rrTD83npUc/NWi4G2keR0pcYE7VsIbN5C4I@AIUD51E6nySsVe7QCzKCtWTkXDYgjcW77m12e2Ll11QxTFbTVVu7nzqdPriayl9onGTtFxo6G6FM4IrWSrzLbgxHNcRarnFwKUrB5ORiOOzKGuXQP@MaJlzkqjYWNWvvJEFe3BjpMt9gf9K1Gz4mL72j1nJjye1pljpe781h8JVmHifNpERa7O6ATnA8@htbdmYdLpOsQxy@kCPNdOQ4/J2PGRPRPJ5EdvykkK12tbGxvnuZ/@8lDxlIRC5Iw2Bgd4n9iTLRF04Pv@dhgcQS9S880k2kuujpHbW2Dp6UlZrkBRvvAyw7t6140yvE3MTe@/R4@NtPv@eWXLxWplYdk0lmmo8tcIt08dWKa9LjOmdImIJbsJGRJ1ufMG49hxvL6BfxqMAqIrtOHHMG@fSqPmxYhpnfnV22SLDqdrh7uGL6rNtiiIslFDn8ZezwKH3KblcUNt5AYlCiLnDkjoj0DueS6llkKr1e3wG3fD47k9/eDW70XO1kefhe07Xuh/S7c8ot3w5JlyYL1/WB/uwesLG5/CCz13bsbsCySt6HFnB4zpzefja1p72/xp1tjx3OPwGDtxQlKDNRq7arPV9QmLnZOKrg2mEQhOjzarh0cqIzsT6guyT1sGVpaDAL2A/Umsbbt9FnY@bHSFG@WY@XJvElZtJn/7pvMM4l3h6jQOoin6RELiyTCdrtzI1JPryysQrD1PQtEQ7k0dp@NDIpONOCvtAckZJNBszrozOxmVhafTmQbgWu6eaIb2zb8bGEtazeS1I4mNiDbJii4gGfJ7PF7J/rxmmlHFCzEIkKHW6RJ03pD@4RDanhIBX0/PYL3DIsZUhjZi4KdNbSD4VcxrWH/eYZiRhIlXHRhS6xr5VijJvrxvFFz2CARy0AAS0/9USya6YMR8fxm3R5QN1n0cukliJRMpC19YXMFVT/7qpcwpka8TlZihdyea/OMzYnB8gynsxp2@e5CD2ELvTItHqabIml7b1P5v09TskqkWjI0n9kZ85EgrywvP/4W7OlemOr5Pwtb1pBp@TnuDWl/n4CMJhEf7xPn1vc88z1hgHtIJ6b1ZsJMVSRVZ8aakuo7L0Y2foSLnAsRMoghj0yw06266mYKt9nQZUWyoXORW32wpnDcUZk1t6j/9f7mIJC/2d6D39@eTDYUgungV1jlvx6MojDxyrNCvFiv4A2bfheORn0uJv5MPUDJsRvTvc527G0nBq/SK3zk@za7J23tnSRmt545a@BG@HjRR/JnnO6Vp4/38qWy3dWd@m5NPeKYku3UWWRmlHEt2fOg078PAZbBfC6B5YN9@B5Ga/Q/4eAZkEQm9ubLMW3cb@LGFCGt@YQzCmmzUC1bS9Oj346aQR9BQbzMw0hlvB@oIp/C1vZ33Fkn68Vyqj4hFw37OarlZfJ@hqvSOxzoAlIahIwm3lsLFjw1jKUk3GsuBrCPwsVWeCOnZ2w5GRRKq8WVZw73ru@Nvd7JszPvUbOSUbT4Bv1edDW6bv1yMbj82FZdNfz5/KY5@fSrUstP1GNqa@kHCexbWqkUOJbqU/p3VT0rMudqBJ9zkGIkI/YlS6tSCyrZh5cfKJcfeNO8Bg@JKS5Vj3qGC@FiN670TlbOKv1Ksdw76Z@V4eQ3XqyMF0uLObz4gVZRkjFyM38yPsOaap@6hv2PCuEzORuodg1R7BpCb14Ho85gt7r3MnUaBwUAR2Da1psP1CXx8xys2eB74vfD65w@JvMUONaBguTMsVdQCa7yfJ6M45hWhzCjUfFIm41u@N@J68wV/avheMBfTJREsJb60vnizBk3piKfKFCRk46JpQj/AoKTlMnhYkjeTsSKOl8Sda0E30nXAnGCmiwOM6eZDHwKgaj25To5cyI/DJqXQAKZzr9wNbW@znnPidUin0/xYMoRjNhhoniGR1yA0J8h3zagCdbcI3b7cKj7@F3Cg7zhM6ox@8mwgbzDmiK@wPxbfWb/Jq6/TgQQws@JzuXrI06teZEiKb6DfLiAsGfpjT@uGeBWKYMyh84CtrRXSYCzpTjTCM1qMtH7uWuQU2hF/@ke5Ev861Y34vKuFGeS8D21/hWBljyk/GkDf7pJtZxVLW@qmcIWKea@SQ2cdNH26HVI02qitsJul5AWWswl5MAj@/fq9hfj9qMTtHkWIy/f87e@51PfffkuSCWlfFrgk0JrdqFM9nNS7qvKJMW8W21VFCsvPo100yeVJClbvq9s5I8HjU5SeCMeSuHK@MN66kPe@vJhxujLlwepOjGDx99P5Lvm7yU98jGWqbIv0u3jr6MHKGTjWW1rMsWlfr/Tfe7oJNn6C9gsQ9RUSqpzGkRlJlVF@2BqcUIaHM75edpuVBIoiyUjcXjOZDbWX2R8rWQ8z02jIV6MtybWjDliUYnbXGTC3bDDIrXDnx9YIBgmGE2ZmbthKk905YkFFqUemGbFC/LWBKeuTU/xCvwiv@AfM9nTyJly2dkf5wTzG@m8eDenCcRC90FmNpnS0gTuIvJSd@qeVSRpezINcbaQ2LNOgeM2Q/HBbuMY/EEsJ2xBYSTFLbrHXzSlkwIlw753DSE@fnX@VnjkvAxIxx52wxtVxTYjYC8sJ@XgPg6jcYTYUBziJroaDru4dWSF75pdqHVYkaVlXLckEK2V3XfqsOyR8h6etEM6VfLVPiBfw0Ak@RBdXVzAmQwesINriFacuHTGvlPtT@RAg@bM4yVxMw8Vgm@wAO52LmwkZORk9oDS0TBohr5DOlpE2o8jXW13dPpQPk@H3wiij9GStuY4/3TVaf6y9RL3uU9Lxccli2Qf9XVw0X/8JHGwIiKZD0sIILhceuI41t1wU@6G8wDoqV0s9G@JN8OPYb8fOlVaMbhgREprFI4@hi3fcQ7C@BIYcMHKuJmEH/bgatSUwx1SugJiRngJR55chxGH4S/WZ7kubvJdmefg0iq5baah/thpgYDG46Q9wO0wX1ggTIDQA5V64ZiI8shVaZT47lnjwrpLDwdRRA3EObHuJmIy9AfjTpNGhk@ynC6BkmuQpLF@awoTaq/ZDeAc7M9CAO4xCQUMAuYq6T4cHH1p/rtwULpj5o49MCNTIOk34LlC0z0cdUj6JgTmUeFqFu40wEev6ofqcH/n6F31oKbo@c3B/tv6dm1bbb7nO25clHNMXvVqf5ekS3ybLrfm@/QiUz2kmhn@4FT33qvaj28OaoeHav9A1V@/2a0TNAJ/UN07qtcOPVXf29o93ubbd4Kg9vaP1G79df2Iih3te9yqqeYk9dT@jnpdO9h6RT@rm/Xd@tF7bnGnfrSHxnCrX1VvqgdH9a3j3eqBenN88Gb/sKbQMWe7fri1W62/rm371D61qWpva3tH6vBVdXd3qqP77/ZqB4qNBKxebtYIy@ombWHREvdzu35Q2zpCh5KnLSIeIbjrqcM3ta06Hmo/1qg71YP3ngZ6WPunYypEH9V29XX1JXXOyX2DKjQuW8cHNURLAiUOjzcPj@pHx0c19XJ/f5tpfVg7eFvfqh2WlbO7f8gEOz6seQr5DrlpgkHUou/0vHl8WGe61feOaM04fgN7B5cG@R0RhrCsUtVtJjDMINBbItL@wXtABR14ADz17lWN3h@ApkytKqgAi4qtI7sYNUhEPLK7qfZqL3frL2t7WzV83geYd/XDmksDVj9EgToMMt4T61Cjx9xrjBPhJY/ErI7hXI@HU9V3VHX7bR2Y69LEAYd1zS1Mtq1XmuY@QvVahyidAc4Mgp59sNK@/epjiOCUt09kZp/RxBGTtva3a7Qi69BWmeTDMa06q1OhlOxvtNLEH@lnKmRNKzy/umh0@u0BfEzjanLw0YsuPGTxcZEC5dS5J5mVPl/hCtlso/G22qCN7mGj4XrfUzOFxrdq6GPw@0q5uo/IjYCdNw5@1taE7uspQm38oC862VAPFxAoKdT/QUzfgl7oqkKhFepqcN4HYHN0FMm1ySWuUkg0srMjcrckTfLJBP/uaHbgijkD3m82cE4Ky0guNIjon/6X5IcsDtYLks5y3FUoYBPLaHQ@haYZaYRDIvA/OiJBp81N@lEY/nKRK9rNYc/vXwwGrZzrmjpcdkz7wIuc@43q5@HFVPX8dH1Glq@ddVqByOy7WYWJ7581yZQeF3/EPcvhn8aY/7gGG4n5gFNTbooPq/WhZe4HqQ6LJE/p0BZwr@BBhs73uvpj/R12c8WlJ@Wp96/i9zK3YC@IMLa04J1wvTP@8@pMCtAE41gcRJKOjpBRKFh1jL1JXPiaCl6i0HWnBcsfWqsvQ17XiSSkyF4FXbtNrMajzo2NPcnhlwfV15vHOzskOoHtk9XlpytlJw679aMnf9@jHY40y1HHhrSOk57Gn6xZskWKD88UK9B3wv7MwIUCCiKWuxk0fok4D7HdRtqSCYIM3Y2QyKgPE71MCDpkFAfgeOAYfp05MzUD5FJdddGbXnDDKn5AuhLzgDZm6U541G7wD2DH099M8bhDmoE0i3HsXeJc2l2w3MvsGFNR3txw4B4U8TOGjyWMW0wDPupi@1l41/IvzdvWKEZiyoj5ysPONQmJB9NYKGNX0ZeZ/YbjjOgDYI4eRm9@1PxGj@91gDsOdxdE4@r4kMi4E9fEOXVyGK07faIhnyGvBoKqmZbWFU75XY0Uzz19nBwHBrFmA6OCpC2w8U0DLsdxRKabZAvYFwuu@iyciuAdgFPWHKt/E@fO6o6GUjbxQ/RvE5VCCaw4yIlQ7TpuwzFF3sdxLAw5U2T6U/Rg@P9AmsyAv047ToKeUMsKAvhdlGSoQivavjJROtfmosG63Uioab96n4D5ag/MZdwxfXtzI/41RAI9OhPz4j2HPWznZhAATI6DDXv@xiZplwFtnV5kXF0d9yT9Zm@YU3qtMEvFLbj5lTOP1S7P3K3gh6tcOWuyGtylquqFbNzOedbTlmlqK68eRhkB55r4H4VHfAAST3jm0kuxWp3mrKKeZUYO6FBL1oLTiiMmkVr69c5bu0fKCpGZkv365ssQikBvAJ/b/eQkIwMl5rnpiIu8EqsjjoKHeOLYJmPx0SHrztkQsxsCzsMWH4YgD8n4GgtEV6BzqL4Emso9ZEMRNJJYHSZxBiFuXZ9Iy8vqdYw9n0yCQ2Psj/sSyj6UUy1TwpcAHxpD213eV6@DCaHc/b5uC4sVHh0OPNguojE5ltD1kXOlORiMSHUM0G/C0etMXF@904cOYT@6Gun4hbSedUb6RMIo/dQM1CbZvfMyIzHkGbWoM4a3Qstn/uAu9UJYiEp4kpv8isoR8xoe3TCHjp2bxZLKrSdf1okmHJaUibiuVtSXL1JKCKpDhoZMwU4Uby7YZpPbwb1DPP2uB6NfsPZDBeq3wlYcmdQCyWeBMkj1Psd4bI6l68NBxCcaNBQ4AYkpUZKDtNhQldbop5qdtF1TJomOidil3JPf307MpMZaihpKGFe3Tsy3kqfBBJWWdGjQOFhoaWmZUZm14fp652aMo4Wmr61V5rQfi5Q1USIqD43qiCeRm/HTezzpQ/7Kwwizh97gjluroEAYOivuVW/LOcYPNgXvOuGoZZ@JkibTCoY4fuOtz6DPvGiODnXYv2YwjsIJ7QCahc5NgWE0cn8ZXPYbW4NucNEZdALapyEM/I1IPDxO@BEDdjEaXEecTog/tKxCrUnyLPFlJAwbfsf3kmUrNFc0Doc520xhPJpULyVMBJ@cwwgwyS7K/D2cjpEW13mynFRy0v6nbI9Xcst31n1cmlVZbvQBQAu4jSkLCvEhHbNjkuV8Wr5V4Py@AhaO5yqvAvcOi70Uxs@IRHwNk8LYIHPLLMHuBHZmd2J80rrxWhyDcIRAS@F2iIw4UY5fewESNpMUeQ5LgTVVWi1aVeUW5QZxCPEwuZvcS0//wdgTAn8C/dLjWdwyixFYxLVNtKVI9is6yijhwuaBHZbRLIlJinUuOn3L/ZCTUNxMQ01/ntxFDbb8IaVIh9m7xZWYkTna@CDrXa5BIqcxcbGoLKgFl@N2QAWpjnPFuxk2/Jb9LE9@XOLKyRkE05aGnLOQvotUTaISUuJOmdfaKEtM5W/PmKWl7x21KQJWZpmcWamZcxmjubAHSkfWV1xrDUYkjDNT1NOmHgvReDBc@E7q3Sk7ZkZmm0Xrput@0xBYmK1Ci@WjFpO2MsHjpOxM4zPFNGmKsaUZ8RC2r/wcs/k0EW8qDcy3SmPyDTrcRbPEbipeVOLxbsncx6L4ERa9ZqGJpxTjjiCl5fj9SYM63rhbgmiYsr1qsMRoQGQ0JvJogZoiU0yl76cQc5/GfYoeLaIc2m0R7ezxuZOo00ZyJuSp@ZQKcgl6InA7nDZJLg3bML5AmDjRcGMhFSucN96Er/JK@XMEGcYHAQitOMwn51BygpsM1hQfcXaAdq4Ba6ESJBE9bdgWDnHQ/5hgHJVfH@5oi4fGJF86KwukmxgS7Sq41H2QjL85/Txp3DCUW6SgKT6DFHGPbsmmy@/v1Z/tC5UjCFKbP2tL36KHzrhqkbChf@xPjRvowElTumZqRqUnQoNFA80F2qVcdEPZrkL764yE42HdoKcRbSDkdQ5/FnUNhPNeKcbURpWb1gRFXE1umW2uym9IlYSh5DfIr6eiqLq8cSUAoWBM9SslgoCwpow9LgU49I7NeSlE9RhRxUoJ05JeclTUxM5zxncQVRd4smyVKM4q8cyGkZ8JhBSL2WUSREhnmV0kgUIL3UxcrBJPZ/cnKUEKseF9oTgNhR6VNA3jkRMCchLooptIlJOS8oqag/njk2U39THmb/76rGh9LU5/JfrEGJ7kS9NfV4upr6lml5bSVVM1iR6u3WrqI5HCtRGOpcKf@49dU@yQ57FNqLXJSGkZ2j4bSbppl0n7Nv/nSK2zU7bRMQw82zPcbL8akmIlFZT9/gDsaoGvDBC7/U/31limGkx0rgCOS2ecXXKyIWSNNYOlHt3CTtdE2osDFJg97aCt3h7t7KTCvp5PjKFRLxwtF4tFMPG5Hfze2FbjKKkzKKRLF9pX3W5heP2X0dvzAsv@MOSUAGtmBx3SkNCkiPzB6EIyQwAHKorSee3Iir3@Vbttp2DADSUGj4ZNSupoCIoXoE5s9PL2iA@AGKReYH9CB9G/n1Q8@64DUTQ1FHMNRbVhEvwxY27PiDx40YZ9dnxTxcAgmI01E61bbmXjM1YQZDbhweLwxe7nxDw58yrsdgeeeoeExIgUMPd1usLOjl2hKEVww8jevVcRx6P1VPix07X8ilHE5nWAMwuTyTNh4sIjNv5BeFG7GeYyJx8ytKxQlxfRzUXEp/ZU5iLj6mDx3wFW@JDQ/q7SvWCYazKdpgvTUq9ncPJEGD0ueTP3PqkiLp@JaZp9uzSIOhtdn4M1UNdd1gVMLHseXu7JHcVj4mZOb0pt0LAoMDROiLnyfTXgavaPE4sfx@3290lFTgMgA/u7JKJkQvlzApHvAHgG6ulH9EQU7b/maVrvTAUUEQUHyTpuyx1UaKCC4zxsVn69zlWrVTU/XFxU1eomPeTzqrpZVdt4sbmptun3Jn7/UFlaXi6LzN12P9PLTfPyq9okGHzCudi8HG3TT/pWgd8YrLUxxPOFyrxXnm9U1jfKUeGkugm3fnr6z3/5n//5r/@rUNU//h0/NvnHyYe4kO/7hfnm5/kfvpbx@2T7bGH@/GR@eLZwUQaX/Y2jhg/q43yQmI/6o3MnK6uA9ZbtSM0@m6PP6KrK5ATsBaNfSLqsqWwzKmT120gyR7GMzTZD630IP8pz2sKbpAPTW3lCIktAJziOp9FphjDAo/WGKEm4wA5U6svdijm4RziYuEB8q5LVkXhYZ/0YwqcliaQAX1xasfKdfhT2cQL@kXVe6Z7jBPS3M25o/i18eB1dbA5u1KPTnHpUVI889SiT4T@llWf01p0vdOCdK8VoO5DJePQluVqAmaGKOqzo8f6Bc@1Mkdtx5jllDyCZMBVcWLzgvHj3x84yknAtunDmkIpTyREJXzKhSvbzfP8rDctnKvE1k3K1YUWhoXcx3Jh1oxKPL1SgIBJDgKTlnhBkbUBN4qaPPZLxVDBv9Fg7nE2IAYOsBy93eN7jBa1F831t85zaSyHNEZvPy1usjWVxhma08UXaTxDgCxXZThbZk3Ahu@CIlbfVS@6meGHb/dPMJ7YOk3BsbNOl0m/KYgKx5rYJN9/Xfi3akFuuV1SmE1@vWE1lpm2/lWNV6V11x52hdlfg1jGhPsetfZWZhBFlQAJHYvav3Z5hfFBgIkVNDYsky5qo1gBdl5nQ167pNMCuLzdHFhEKH3I0t79MzW23wF4ihh2EBxip2JSvHXS6kY66MmJiXwSjc2QHDNqcUG0s92Z8nofsq1MYD9ox0j5DZpPzZD5TV7LDUXDRCzyV3RscjYJJnZYt0nzGTd@lHiIEE5DA5NNNz@qeQVh6pIeEKRJ3hS2HkLygO9Hp0WRsM7HPCYbUTAUddgWTIMVOTMnwS2qspuiYcPXvGAQb5VvCO76N1CKWJS8sjTSkjO02w9Ps1tRxTAv23IknTsYRVOOZaXhBV7rCQtvji1@S5F3ECNBtZ7QXoHZFWHmG9rE6XYT9ILU4DbuOcfQvlJWsi5jPnIpSrJEckye1lGS8A1akR35IR4GQtcmEM3Lmcrm500inc8va6wgH@Y5t8QuB6sQJ6DiBGXuGqON@R4Tl1AqV5MDwVZ0t/wlCuxtcEH6T62ACVjzN5p4/KLgnH077Z49yp/0vp59cxkSLZLPK5lVWX2YbiaXnCq2MBS/101ilRSbU4Gk/XeC0r8SHxSIBIVLInXwonH0pEEKnWWSlP80KQVJDBkwK97dXAPjCLTSzaSwKWWfOfeSawc89L7mK1lb@izGUF678JSzMppKP6WmfM2oTKPbT/fVKXE6iwupS8clS6QnthC7Cm/wovMJ6m4@uzsMbUiUibGdp6Tn9lOKGFCG@3kRBmV7eUD8lrYn4nkTaSUmLUD3NuR0nZiuq4wtPUHmiModLhYuLG5cJcPmIDb@niOVMWY4FJaaDFvflsH5Ggx7aCSLItWnvEOFIWBmIjQgfoeYB2SRfuYtDXTNdFtjPyVdbiN3KQGh4C1lrtegP@nmtrLn@QhlKNLxmuqvF1eL0HL01RVMzdF4rUwsPVGnj@dP/@Lf9X7Pj7MZS4d2I/o6zv2ZXVrPySA/067H59TG7kV1HsZWv2UmB9sD0@PQ//jfV3/gLwcGXyTr9s7FsYK1Mshv5Clf5kt1YoYfS0hK1@3/@@Z@pD/OyY0Mu1vmGpxixsqHIVtBn3qXvqo5eyrZ0IREr7JgFGGJhSHtz@gHDqJul1SIf02W1VcXHUEe@MvYoeolnw6wxmwrJSYaxpyDNSCpU0EBeQBoTiraybDeM2QaYN0FT/fTQX4loB/CTNueIm4xNNx5GMBmal20RDWBOWqT9vDxsFJ9nYvOOtYyxKSkbFRJbOy1rVx@XiR3eDMJxp5m2kjDTtdcMrsNzH3zoh60r2lP1o@7g51HhI7Fkr7S0WmjjcL/AdtyFIUPKDyf@J1IEdTIg2hiy0amnRjQCgx5CeHmcLYgU@p34TsrkkyQtexg25QwrnZOYioiPnyfXw@iOn6jSOf6XFHhkztSJIK1caad9qrl/sKYyi3FBKcd7XhfYvGHjWB0CIy/WsEOWTb7DfcDpoOmPXx1dsBMS10LUdSniB61WI9Dfcs5cxqRK85y5y7A7rGTaEt4dsVNxY6LpL2rmnVDyHZwg5PMs6ACrF44D2qJXMvwG@/GkBYRJ0Xetcai4hKxtXVbv6lsVzrpyT9PX0vQ1jSi0hKSdmGesaGzKLiaypYKjylHYwJXazIaptcgkbR75/AcYRDIs9TbcEnR32AOSqJZ0R1uV2cPm8V6YeOQ6FJ89OVqUzNVONnF@9EwJ8aCG7oR2fWmMBASi4K7BQpl@H4oHRMWkGe30HYnnN/XZxPfQYLgP@wglaoetk@Cjsiz1PyL3TWfMvpSKSKDjyto22I6sHjHoOMRWnII2g4OXjAuWaq/xZosLmuFY4zTQJiRUJiPnVCdNFaeXbevstZIogl5kiqWlx0@WV56uPkOWsznd29lgUMnHLmB4GRAM1qhztMnG@0ols5CRV0hBfbtJQJ8FFhdwMOu6dl0T9vnafVApFTWwYoZhXXMaDamujysZZAJxFPpYEWiPkhtlcrnnayfo2Nlpy/1C/xN/m/iAzHAmHG0gpLfG4U0SmcrpScCBCgtmDoqTe4wIKq7@YpcNB@0DRJsIYesqbE8N7SICxPhyNLi6uLS5w9ehrY5owhDBOS41dlAvw3ESYMzCCrqoPnCoW94XFQPv5HYPYJSLJQE6nwCnaabjVgba0hSzY4EWIUTWhMcqrhAt01GbnZk7@wNV29ueRixrp6FjuL5t2UrKHUcyQwAZ5Oq1untE1NXRLtiVVMskLxVVmQVcEeVK7A4fwFe6iUTUFlWMrGa9YZy7jywl5sUktGlSlcYReM2AWSp@m5TGr9X0AgQxglCfJsVCzIvvc2ySJTjZg4x5Cl7OrFk2oq87UcQB5nRjGVdblHIhziow59wBEOc2xYx0pLiGEeXHGideltFGMkfxisbRgDZDjneq4cySnGaCrW4jCYCNrOOGFuh/fW/LU9s1@mfn3bYHRXmz@lf0O07xfDe@JY1vaU3Vd8wQ2NFi2eYWNlO/wkWJmKWoA8YmCEL4tiUrYphEDajVdzTtZVKfpOb2WcIVYNdAK@HmdFRPEgR64TOQOb15j0NxsLsOv1uTw6vbkiYOqaKnhRxx3T@xLZrMJa3GkISU3wFiaRpEHKgl4fa5hOHFAp0170DvXQxj13dm83SKZWVDRWr7ToHInubZOylzH1ssabZYWsM43scXzLf38sZ52B5oX7SYOb7BGw/@GG/kv5858v8tmKP2j@GOx5o7Hq9B9gh3xGHD2aOT07APZnDM@YTX4Earc9HB@VDb@olOFD0LAAs8YAgfUvpYKqJvd4gTlZv9YXF6PYKR0NIyHAP@UOef6M4/WYPM5cft8L9q5/N/584v684vr2GtmTHyWrWzwq3/fXqcqIS59IuZwwt1V4q5f7SnK7qnK2tYTWcM8//3nub/H/X0qe7p0zVETJALBwlffz83iyZSPdyq1xNzC9/RQbtyyGM/mytd7L1alQxtHtrdq@iyAm1d/WH8VzX@q5BG/IQ0dLiLiG1D4728bE/FWV40Sz7lUHCykp5If01kdKu/esFK9iN6gRIhzQdbI71RIYXck4/JbZOf6I@J9I0Xn@/FWWS7TpaJi3NrAy07wpKbTHHRfHWSzKWVeF3Z5hjIauvoYHfxfwgZesEv2guNkMfQXofdrllJ7C3YURx1SnfG6g5gH@o9R4pVNDkZ2bH29o7ZZe5uqcaBLabWxdmbBLlqw/0f7aV60DesrNw4MiLa@Lq@2VXBNNdsL@QN9V0Kze6y7vEf4tJnmkufrakDvTG4i1SBPvDTvJjs05aWl@9bA6SWjz@YgEWPyt8zq/4v)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/xc75l)

oksh is separated from posh by `~+`, which is [not expanded](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/p/posh/posh_0.14.1_changelog) in posh:

```sh
[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo 354
```

Answer (score 1):

## 355. [Sphinx](https://github.com/mwerezak/sphinx-lang), 15914 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11    .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo 354;;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';                   # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppp  ;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{














































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata@#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F ._#giogrl614op>a>std[]!!92[ ]?42e>805在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 /._++.._# !._++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:  ~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#$/````(print 346)9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@_  pS9^7^8^MUOUOF
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD4o6Ph/SNSoLpIigRAgN@kSJVKpepSd1WppqTq7mmSxQJJkEQLBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAgk8uPly5eZL9/Lj4eO7g1/9rMYXuypY80HljNhE8ObsJ5rnhquzO7N2V3d9PJaVhAw1q47mI4Me@JVhBhTGbN0ezDVBwbrm9bEcNPMMwzWMSznDMI1xran9tQzenV4yzJmG2fswO6aPYDAJs6JYZuvDRfCcozdN6yL0cWEdZ3RSLd7Hhu7pj2h0DxjT3V46U@7J0zveBNX705Mx4agAmPPbUsfdXo6o@hj1@CJigxAdU8ozXJIibHHjusZkIPTNTzPQc8yeOqu6TzaffLRlfhqhn2kA1Jjy5hdyV5V2Wem4fauptDYp8cPHlz1zbJPJMdmD66jpObY7nTiHEyuws@z3YFh60yTy7J2NbAAxJwYVilTylwNKkJ9GhOzu5QPBDwwXahd3a9F1tVtqC2syy1mjMaTOZN4/euWFdatx3SPTb2pblE8ezrqGG4Q0Zvo7sS0B@zMnAzZZGh6YTqK7Y31riH1DMscmROjxywTEjl9HwqAtnvsxJifOS5UuQ/Tsa05JDS6Zt/EJAEeABCvxGRocDgjfQ6VbE@gcTCdeYCGZQTQkkIM4t83OtMBc6aT8XTCALee6ekdC4B25qxn9PWpNUmzDoQBkcn/bGjYfmMGcDKAOHY4Vl9OCTVj0eb1Xo9loB0DHicGM4FqhFaFZbPgzxwXqAaxAox8YNSueRmNGdQZVFHfqbB8JgPh@6EPYqtbnuMjs4waBtrQV6nOEO5T1xm4@gio0TOIpp8ePGVe13HhDX4Yl/enm8B09Qnb3mbx/Sf346weVovsdoSwimrsHKogFgSyU92aQguJ1oQD9eOGqQWssvhGvMLiQBYtw3I5loNuW2JaHoikZsrggP6vZVX4FZhWYjkVelA@nsZ8@q4@MC2DQxkglCI2fC3PNLhnciyrlnjMgWP1ebQuZVZk2RIrFFkxz4pwL7OyBrkh6BxTy3n4FeAH0MqAigq/bI4DWrR7aKfY1vZYXx@Z1tyHTuC7LK@yIkAEfFWArJUAAjyzWfxl4UdoLV9R2JMhUHuonwJ4yTJPkBsZIUPCKlTgoWxtKcQRkeXy7L0hZg@kA6LlS6wI2ReAEjlAASirlSD7fIYXxBsaluUnG3qYjLAtZuAHmBeBDiWgfgZomUFiFuEH78DvNGBsGnAxDRiTBsxE08CdxSwgXgHCClCVBZ9eQ907gYx4PlqPiA8cHcCoSG1kYioSCSBAbbEs1FmB5aAhZLEh5LMM8AdcigUGfKykslKOlYoM6FnOMKgbFfDCVqIC/1QBHxWBQf2r0ABUwEkFaqsAVM3mmRAhtprFcEibhbRAGjUHaXLghopTC/iDdNAyVMhShTw1rbxohICblofy5rPUOrUC1G4RwoBuGuCqQXPSAFutBOGYtgQ0LGHjLcbTnBA60gFqBZs7tEMgRh7wIbgQF9xaMcvpp1vjod5Bbs1TdvqYtIDdoIBkhKQZLB48c0hNQCUDYLAXAPoatIAskCMLVZvNYfaXAnRgPlxH2R9wic@w6yMzQ4YNzMohVrxokwk7YDdJ4I7LnBNYmQVtE4aLro5sDTu5QUwqgGNOZAaZwNhqOKcoCxCnWcrGI27UcXHoh6GjZ7guw7ggL3hp4lvetOMZr6Y4OC3w6gMjNIBf9nXTChGgzqlPiKvCM@5BfvNltPuuM6IePEK@ZDnOeM0YAFzwDAE9dM6MBeoLJqmPxxYMReBv8JEQkDnTSYghiSeaK0cIEmG67tAEgJQVsHDTNbpEe7/okDoLzH4ZxQrT6neyCOVeZIzKsrED/NvDNPbUsioweBhdlq0rPeNUQR8@ji2PX4hDMLLB@OSD6OgggCDmhEUI6Y4m05h5HNSs54yWi8aZ1kFY9KGJo411ps@h9vrAr4yZPgIxiaEsYsMIOYIWw2sQawIEQSzWAes5dnwSQjlzQTKAQoclIekDaTIxRwaIlA4kwRrPEdLIMgmzzhyaMlErJ5MMyTG5QihZuEoo7pGLePDOAmNob9pFqmHepk0tCMYeDwUn19B73E@YuKzZ1OHnwiA59sVmGR0Y8QhRi0hdMMIaQH1fnOkSRBz4DdsDWc2TmYlCLbT8gdOHxnZmQtlBXIKkC9hdIgKSIPSayV1ZIJJjAxqdWMxk3fGYgT8IIdA8H2RKMK47X5rsNQRaQ5DLulPXnbPZGGrCHEGsSdfp96H1vjbGQwDBRj3WnXehe0IlY@sReg5xpO54uZiLt00D4tgo6e09/TobGEB2kAL6KPJjk18UYDymIhApdJtLCLYOlMIidMdzIguACVP0HUdG/55jeNRYHPck7PqYmWcMqGtAP@svmNEIJR5opTZJaj3gPH73QviYobCyMJiV3wo@MmzoOl1oldDpofqwTndZHzSXiFyAwpve7Rrjid9OHGJnph0Rog4foBBFvpIPTPaGwuZdtn2l1UDUsOVEBAQUKhH1sS/b6chrffUIRAbbWMjxnLNY82vZQ4zTK7mLLzHOEgYvxTU4jKlLoERJTGI6QVaC3NHsDpEXTpDbkBADvc2dXi8@@EWzd0dM6od5IzYqsB1BVkIvxGM9DAl@1nVA8thCWPUlD4y65HELaN0brYDshEhavaivrOgyMMXbgI4c21kBFYgZwsUoyyFUF9QYj5Br6FbYGKm7eEt1hAx7obHjQAZj6HjsuNAzONOZk3pGVRZpXb5WkwjHiiRo@8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoKxBbocdTHsqSCu6sApgIlxrQN4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidEevnjQnGUts2UOLV3TkHAsWD4RkymjPTdYENnuIgwcegYDCRqZ3CmAD6F3JWJAf1@6uZy9ii96Ydc3ZVtemip/ylJ5zqLuujVuOC0AGdKBHve/FklfwpZSRIVJzxRKGk/C5CRIokQ5Un@qAowSDxABjN0dzuJsSlLiammTid9EtiEhyYkMto7GN9PLmK3Zfgh41mdAL9mt6qbADDtyTBXUI/wgQDFBkDdBfkDOiEILqXy72Ozi6Ae4CKPtuj1Chk0lOVc2Feht0L8/IJgbhEyyvzLDy3Sw4pMqphCTA6lZwGiSUCviMlKKEIHorij63oQdIeDyO5hntObZrcYAkuiiTZeSjswwCQIGRMED7Mrjlp@@LKnTuB4LJRq0FjA2kK2GYvGVUTglkgGTg1RJZJGvEzkSfO0QT7RiIJ5cXIlxwbEJugpdbq7HwydKHH0fulAJGArIKNLTkgrF/PT8yTae9qRdvoiZFE7HUgNJndiVgVYPDnvaF2E1XjS1QFVSKOVMXGi@kJ9LXGS75YoaIfzTU8FH9rPiqRGk4gBn5bXUkintT3WzTovXnX8kUC7oLOzrlRB9A/8WcHQkaU9mWCoNNe66kcCHYHDoc93T1@WPP7Ig9UOqZdWfKwnK5ukfcmRheDtI8O7j3bffb19goYltmpXPVQzFypgEPtdCYN7KmSk7XKZhTGAvD99s2wMeFyHFHwg5nkzCKi0rwLg8ssIOfhs0@ukgQkISQH5QBu/F0RaXgcELqEju4NrwzCbJBKQZZhkiAukw5YADN0IOoYrgf4PJ2@fo2VdxWpse@PmFlTnQMIPJUDO0gnY@AVASwI6vT5iEhpQQo1bZy9XbiiMQN8PkKp@SoyJEpHmsxHhw/2n9UIrD9ZIVEUxZuALKW7PRnavDXtGcKqOMD@wNVlKXmBOMrThOtKAne7SwRe1C1bAx8AoK4jO0yyRkHRvCHgvne1bOQrdcMWQO8E4apcGZWHuu@LaAQPHOK6qPKuGkUpYDFYhV4rR6wwdHnY6ubzRjFXjg5b3UWevShQmmmFcSCQG10IOvEk9JEXUqQvVvvoHz26hrhHQiSoAlKAmWcxmfLyLAG1F8lkcU/ZAw3NsQz5M@J4IhOTihIPJlvlrkfKZyT@/sycJDJJ/lSTEBdy39090O4Hkf15QJrJIKUBdXEcmdw@Lpp0PWgjtmM5A4dtQRouHQYZgti0tpi7A8e@VkM6emJRY7juAvwXJ270MYw15mtSHClVVF3lKzi67Z0Bl1YLWSQSUYhAKRRf/lI/1YFci3IfHXyxD4OIms9kQneGLiBBJA2RC13diC95MAkykn18VhYwXIO51tuDACmyCIKF9hldmHB3EbzSkzimrKyMvxKlj51rFP/SmV9pWuDDmxY4IiQ7ePL00cGT/ce7nzcnWj6/9J7LlAtAOMivA7KQPOR0w966xbsmFgvBxaBvuNi9gAtMQUEJpuCnnguMW8YoMkdgTavhq1eJj52hHfeSVwtzhqHSl3aXN6HH2Pl4VD8hKNo9C5URly8B4niO7Wc4mYy9iqJALx9OOzIorcqXXcfSBwqlg4HBshQVVZeDQ5zX8FalAGS8ucFT8MktEB3mNIOoWyMHlBdaSETWwBIcPM1aWeZgCLowrjYablIOWzCVRumBhgC6shKWjRgwvQFt/WdQTyJv2h@oWom3azWj5RQxiLbU/SHuRt8A1SkBoxWQInnllTXvNO@wOXBphHQVSIzJWzTJ4TEcCywGgiTNmqKeHxCHuAXOlyKvIBq9muJsLnApJZ/JFdVCXgG1DNQ0kFklnHOTRvqkO5QmjgTwJKdP8waRVtj3urrdl7d8R4AsyH0fQlGzjRfNpt0CAb15h3DDxbzGvNVQW8kqu55ky4@frELrXSoett3AA9ouOaFp0pOt4Wc9/To76@nUu3pMmYzG/pgjjdnjXRCkXjvAr3tGtO9hAiUaqGwtxVUw8htlxYSQhUkFvCGlFOhQMNJC01MQLwmEXhQPoeUA34okYIvZDF4Ovmge4SOodGO7N524RzP/KNfgbKk3BiLSZHMXubSH84MTGB3Dlo9cGioXmTQ7M@I4j657fLYSEvkLp0F60NVCCDQrH85I2@FSMTQCSkXqOXAOaFc4bTpczDKi0g8tDTIknHDyASQIm1YPBsBnIDEvyC4vCM@JfJaLdGI7ZzZC6xisJHXMCZ/sd6YuLiCavWjZIHpW43EAGhUuwtdppbFjdPksK09MpQAlUGcjY@TgVAJIV8QKDCqCzlcpURf0cMYaulVGwmUYgC@xu3vAxboGny@SRqhEQZPaZ/GJq@xKXyi69Bpa8w2yFRY@UsV@pR8HBFheM6ZZEn8GlKQTZ0SRPqP5Fgy8F4i7wng@GUKJoYWJes0ZG/ZVnY9rhIlkldZ243Fg@KadOI9vbGzEK/F6PA2uHXBto2sHXSlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/VvyyEUCeJVvYBmYoObw2xwm9UalkW2m9ofpPDZ9JqAqgPMSW8AFw4slaDZ3JpFg/wzUbkN8jZd/DtnPUdc2xT4KPQSDg7z4NskQEUO9RmneNKuqmN1NkVHNBaTRQxEy48WYj02w1z5u9VPMynsbUyapeA/0QmNckMZIHrjMdg@DWyFUk4G3JRrbSqnZq8Ux8K5EoSRZkpCeTH5aSKZ3TOhE3oE0lms04kNSnTqM7dAneLK0lkyGhAI@@CVqGZSXi8nkJ8u8kW8lUHNIm42lgy7V4HOjSRSJ4VGicEeCN6IE5A1JCx4QhLrqmQAySFqewu35hjIdzNxohnHUDKRtn0BcbAHCfBHLxKJd8zdNHBbolTT@Qe3k8EG5x8g7lpfGcc3eBY9pUlrabBOPuqdQfORNd@VQGpUmODJfxjbgiSTASUgiHRMV@bHrYhXXbcKZedKZx5QQo5g6@x8MpMMtgz08aWpU5Fozu0GHxzbsAnYXrPTiU4NKVxBfAAgC9rgw/ZKIoleBiCUgXtEvDBL5I@1toVkYlJDjrCebm84XxKznMrUppWAYzMge24xoSkARSCLQlhTY6CXXm74o5oJmva@sSfigNaah4mwZwxAeWoxNtObuOrAeNR5H0oJ9DkmdGT7CAf/SBPcq8Llyjp2wJtErruEMYIaA0yIm1sLZGfoDieOOePJlBUiGBA240kGt3IHSesZ6maYVuvl8JwrBVALGHUEmoldqg4gZBkgqBSb@S9/m0UKCjPzm8v8/nTmiwxeEV59HaI6c3BbnS15ueGfYgzfahPZm2MzKBDEH61yfWM8eZcC0fXtbNzHCl2RxNLZ3mfK5Oy9yYrut0HIumgm5Kuog/dT3d0vkkVBC6@@ljkPWfHx/V5EokkqKfjm7MG@chV2fL6XkQXXOk9dZgecjjDVPczIs4bgVb6ZDN@AEFDJj6G@mgjgL/IvoHXQrXUHz/EvqPcBMdyMr@LAK9hp5@xDJFxI11uIvI9zxXM5fov1YHC@OpFI8Ljgtsz1WN/E8n/f6Sd5a8TyRkTdbCO0fefIPdko4YRSnPI@Fuu6U4UUAFihNuulsbr0jxxrQDTw5XFh@HmxCGhhUsLT4DiQWXz2DQt1CuAqUFRXS@Mc4ACXuMqyTEunHtjXVBCPWuzWdAZxtLPLYQ26AOBIObgiKNsKkwf@67Sl3Idvw1S4@zVQd0fppW2a7zVW7UqVyuzil8Vn6zDSC269VgF9O6aJhTPB5GI6iEG6SgYtLC/rWihts0PJpsFyhJVfAUUCdmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrTPQS/BLWibd5SBUcUM19GrGoTEfRm2M2cSSHwYi09cd4fAZ1hqtkxKqJ@p3XesnsRXyaDBMK5fYQX5mxTCrXH@DkjDdINdcbQtkSdF/hrZUHcN7pUqrV@PENmCFwKC7nPOLk7SpxesAUPeqeyNLXPSYpfyxGkPkSSTqWtf3azHZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdZx992si0OARhpOPKV4nX4izY8wmCMwhKuDkXXLhTZ2JOSBKgnQgmlleVAakZLZIA@gCDZ1BlYUZ@iRD1C@NiUZa@AZpqwkDMvfkozYzkpdy39MnEsHmb48uP68nN14n8bGqU/Y6/6FBhGVqZAcnUxDBAscqOju/vP3smQ8v1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNYVOqBktPAV9mEvzj7ENElU2wXoaqB9tP300Kir0OhB/4DckXcMDDcBnklcfOmCN613UUIuofkEwv1W3QnRKASWMJJQJgJWWYn/c5urWj6eFWjxKaIkkDtxpwK0NZPy1DZfyR4MNCS3QpQ4V1ZhvKhtJoiLbapJaj2uOcKlY9CwSGiEEjQaTHoNXA4ii6zVqvI9ABAXFTB3gNQVRaoK2hpcU4Oqr4E3iDQEwU9ee8NeNDJSuZXaXAWKNpf5u3p5@SNwEcIyaM9Yme1mgvr7tY7MceBrgZxzPyd1@sqW9grb5A6RzzlT9GDDFDEd2l@1vE9qeRcWdDJkJTQVgwUJWELM33Ptt1kKJ84POg8mI49Ekp2HRNeQ5OzigmjINjVGNASXynhlXAbaJzCmRw6U5pG/3zoqHVBv9TeSYJ9tCmKgZi2v1GIIF@GV0yvSqXQqRtNx6dC0Txxa7wld7Yys5lEiDFOPTqzrKfumN6TbUtQQBx5XW4edN@r06bYiAi17@Avq5EET6r4sDEKkrjyjB82tr8h5eRPJUrYdoz@1B7T6iG4mvbolplQuUeR@p2OuiwpEwH1hwXNFNGBS2J41OSerwQZunIqB8QgYF9deFkW/uv@ILdEdRocJpPKf//kbPaD/9doZwkCBM4@how1DN9aU1F9bWX5SfKHb6orlE@RTy9SJMOS6DWRXd6FIuhU6VoOmRXhJguF/hEsKfo1D28QbSI03NDOOOV8RDJ6rM1m1qGYDy@yui3tlPxbPipZ/QLHrERG4EGQalIhYF68EY8aXYCIqNrKx25EKNk0xasy83ofTyZTfQXC9tRLNMf5u6pt@zExe76gGqI56xzRuqHJXP5n2HGl8Mgjl1MKKuIvS0xqwBOKAvxzcRufq4vMCuuYAxtnguS7aYmhTzuhxW6vw7Kk3ljqkhff4G3WE0Q05uBa/r4ti@ieiQsd6qpkW3d6xJfrQoaH4uyEU3GsqRYhmXiGzpXfmKIMM37@VhTsLgOPUuqlUJrtmaXk8Xp8eNUlKXy6vTj2Tu5weq@YIFL6fVeKzaFRgf4frLbUKw5U50i1J60Wca5n5qo0J16KGa5qUxjjFFZ3TlTW3oD4OSN2ppbsL1w1NfIFHsIywbkbaHzaeml0HxIExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJYZbI1bZITbiekW2f5griJjD9RCHMSl0LWaBTjdCW4ZXdOm3oGh8a2auCE20khkZx2lus4Z/taKD0NQTfl99Yj2eiVW78CcJKtr6TCOrx0OliYHcfLxloZ6ZnoG3VYT9mQlopOutdJ/uQsE037RabzbmrVnWo7Hjuh@E4EGLlCB31c36CgtTd2WaDI86r6BBwV7HBYVqlsDxyqUBooOt7W1PnX7yPf957tyuJBDqeotHCoQfxxb9Z9r@fqJ4p7cVkF0CszF/a0R5w1D7Co25a@9rC8dKAa4cLe6ZA8yJUopK3yqb03GuORyps@D588xdKwjbTB0jOckToN0hwnKJXBMXC5i/zy55W7OrfduTOka2OJthYhU7ollwGBF92tVyrSM@p4p1Ezm3VlU35oaU2OlonHY@dLAs8o3KBnvjlTGL8amP1OPiwN4NCWM9drXDN8Jaxyn8e1GZqJbZte4XZRZZmpjkL7HqDo/BcdTdFxPMbCn46VaXdLO7Gc3k2w4Drq001vCDkPelw@VbpGUluRzz6DfjRoT1/Bwg1gtl8lkfAEmsuKy9HKTJpUN035p8vtSxuSzyHkRF1fZ3IhzdR5ElugWxLUsSFun2FPkclmxTduYzPH@jty04zjW@9QUMNWeiaIYSJa01famGrsm7viHSNhi6sLDCY9Of92kBR9tfN0S6INK802VHl0SeqfalHDRc4QLUsuvN0/fRBaYbssFD3PjnBDffGutlyX92RBVLsnFG3sdl1CdjmHp/DEr5G6CV5azN8JbZhr@Yi0u7vIl3cVSfOwKUxrPgVhmD7SUoTEy6PUGKV/vod0B/7E20szB37rgmWF0ldm@0V0XYWwCX7DxvrSGHBGWJo4N@tUE9/mhnmLhTlLfdx0HDlb9VhL5YKQPDG4I4yZOuZiwwN00XK1bOFdPXVT4DpouJFtYOFjfJKBTnRhzL3iuBPh43oV6nY5un2670vm7OAf6Dr193RbW60OsPXSG9tAY8n3j4du6zgHtccINl9yEOmA9GOJWtvF4aYt7lJ6WY1nvQk9kjZxROk5/JU77ePgVT269F9y53oEA/3Hr5J0@4bwDHWt7zdCYwrjkORNnbEj0ti6qhRM9/L6OhwaL1D/vDNKNej5QJHj@vPBv1S0HujMZj@nRHltTj26UVKIzy7fJTX2@NYU2RTruQH7tjDqy7yn7@1ZoCXw1i@mYk@4QD43zlm0MnE53aN6GdMfQJ7Z5ogRTPvz1nXRXpIzJpPvoLVsmkNedy9heatHwI3wcrKt0f/aID2uh4wZ5ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6HoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3yuvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEuhYh7u/e2KtZEVnJBZs2N9VsbaVkpCOArlkZEDgUddlu7zPLdLFsll@W4dQtJSEUWRfyvuQ29/7Q7ODZmTeFvyX2tfSpqWVg5w9nA686wyTT9f3QETD2/ppC9rLHJmyhjFLt/3HOjJrloKHHOHZBplraty4ppK/cVGF4qmWpDsmPNrwgKqbrp1Ds8yxx@9M6q9divP3MoEufnW9kNNmvlqZ9iumZ/T5Egi6bhMRR46LO5FBBpG6uJKOM@jIzLngxRmX7QyAqUsWW0QO4q4TW1ZuE1pd/eGYKX3@xBjouNf6kTnBzZorWgU12VXbi26F/bWp7plfm0LJ1jU2tNjAlyHd6NF@fFsB77E@MLsPlyoiRNInsL/Tkz@Wmj96Xa@Ls6Hp4Y6m0HHDxBQ2Od6IsdW1QW9YEfPqvH1orGLRgfgxyJWxV82tO@M5nhabk@umaXVzQrOs/nOd6rhuE9iNSJxNR@Op5z9W40B7pqKz0KMT8vfOTAAuvQLWyoa6NVk9Ux2ZcgUpzB8UF8510vgXpuUM2BelDAOhDYQwFM5XNJx7MDw/xQ05rr2iJVLe77jsiRMdkssL9grq1sgyybTNyc2zOZMJbs4JnlgYPnLgCQXlEd7lu@8LQTpeTZFHt8v6i6PJt4zv0PKOnKnbNdAZ2huJqgV@rsZesPsYT3Q4aC/lLKqldR0Luhc4rJVdpuvY04nkTu0bR4XCjaNChc1KhUgzYImv7T9@noy2BtqtfZsUaoDyN/Ws@cK1dsPAlUZm2iCIreejy7EDXeI@t5P0jLYK35JmF405dYld33dW6TtP5zCAvLPCBMx/OrpvdHHZ8Na8nziPHduB0WgMjHL0zOBn/pc2eqxOiMke4al2oE/v1myOCOyaQYhLG/rY6ED9WgvXu4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpD0v9B1a1sxrY7hfkmTfhH3OpV2GaGHxox0i/UNhvdBadLtcpEY5@OW@sjSio03dhyb34nbZuChPr6Zq8BQQLd3XyiXcSP@0rzASv1suaiHp3yXiNHjRinWldU1Oo7F7zfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjQPyK@SYBNKXdyMPKd7IQxaqEUiyp7pHi/SrVY0FSHX2HluAhrrbdXAlzHfcsDsnYpjgFjYd7u3nGwc6QPgZcCy9O/UtMN6GljXqjOi2VmGI1OYzo4OngjpkzWOiz65XJp8Z8k0ZRHZ0hQYAAnaFnbrAEk9BG0nePmwt6VHLVDXHdCNOvXa5nDbrSLZpdF/rOGvmEL0Wc9NL4VBm5Qk518xVR7oRzSIrOp10X9mTlreugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xumt4OzKysWA@ZjgxcZF5ehVkrujrekArrrF5PD5mra0i@rT/gJaHdPy4fSrtrJU8ED/@H9z5WYBBuF3KB6RFgXbev4APyU9f2H@/SAp863qRvzg4BbzwFsI6dYLHykAQevGega2tdIaD27KnFZx8GkX1Xox6pYxKZtpUki9j1xJAM@1QiQ3Cz6yVy@KEvZRdNok6MnuTbQcCVBulRcP4rjOY/VyygRnkjbvZUFU7YWSHnb/9cRdyzgDOAvOVMpLFHT2XsPT14dHgsjz115fi0O8TTEdfkuCXDClopE5mS@lJ3I@udfDtaz/Qmyr0jVdp7dCBjhDX05isaEjxwZW7psXbe07c3qiv6Wi0IQ43JagHx4fHjR6nFEU2W2Bu6zshIRoP3jo7SeNLk46OVwdHUD6B39J3Z2uQH@6qaXNF8n9u0OriOe67IaR2kYwO0UWiMD7ldlluFq64zNnrH87HxKQyeyMG9d8y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXEoo6KivLhVwysjMblG3DDZ/r6vPEHCO37NJD4Y@121FQcsgqbna19HDTiv9VKYZl/J0I75dIzVxvrRNTgp4xGKJL0b2/L2Kqqq6j85Heh3pl@bWVtRxh1fqw5Zy@w1Ky4SsvUuglTaBVSeat@8iL0ghYt4I3nJ73PcHZWbsN5iYAoXdhZYc/M@y5bku0lnWTeFGB1Lip7cYoXxjvsCAV7vA5RQvQK9f4wi31LNElZ/KWjI/dSJK9vXsHtyV45tPy5lgfPXnOnuoeGiG5OWIUY@MdMF5IRl9KOG@FFvDWLqf2XACl3QhvMF7dnyvsSHd7jj2f3b4IR2dQcWgn48IhLHyjSIZlzsxVY1WXz2s9Xb3N6La8@SEOZ74kB0eN0/iA3n77n6lqJkOmh/CpZvjrLTUTdHCWQJc@R3t20aDjg5A1dFFukcEjuVIbfWTMcDsKnw1epdSvHN8KN4x9xeT64eSmsNINYbkb8rsWhp4sK2fUGwDmbwhjeTkMfuRYZ0NH3tNdw1ux/3glQjcVpHxDQcoR7vy6lMFJUFpY9N3rRXw8uuA/VrbWY2Pi5sZDp2PmVpZht49GJtljNJZ@PdzfTqG7tL1l4PhHPvj76vzOpsbKjB7rr1cHEKc5WRkETNAYTulIxPXg5QXSDsi8hj0wuX1Fds@Z7NPbDYpZeOJ59V4Ec3x/Ol6PMfBGtPN/lZ0vRfwMdGbnzGP38GjcQkxfofvj/rjV/utkWhZODKKZ0YfHu0HrOjxStEiOCyw@f7rkjYdHJ4dHET/XmM3WKb3SbJ0OuTJkkeuT49xSttv1F6criLX@vBGIG8CPw@daOYgzu4@PrrMEVN@Gk5EVhHys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm4MvDpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlsV5nZXeC8p9jAgmybk7SntNlrWb7fXtcpj43NaewAxiE24WMKB@oaXjFluGGBISdZ2VOdkIfwsoXs0Hpr27HoQP6r5bGpHzXx7ad9QCz/azA@UenJgiz2RsFOpZHL5ayLR07FoDDexicYgN@kkLMS9uGAb/ulTCBCD86z@eVu0GQfasIEHZgUCMaltQja1mpovsx38fEcFZN0k5YheZJkryKvBNs/9o6SVinrJNmpMrIjMP8wbGtrlxmIBLpq5hDIx6URlmxMI2QwOojL67gG7YKQ/g8Cu5jPwJivRI/lV/6guoLR5/vTg6f7R8e7x86NGpnXpH@UNCmHbkFtgMODDbE@Esvtkg3GZm46mI@QWZEffZEC92wvKxaBkV4pWWyraolDiDqbZPLdtRaHTzIp0CfhJIs@NQrF1gReHHZSY6sc/yF7hB4vpfDRUEQctUp5QZxWWWZXxWIcxZtP2w69@a4ZC8VtEFfwaEWbsW/uFhjhwnJ6fo2ew268gxwe7B4@eP9tnAYKLRnNm9ibDWjnPjUFzCwtQT32TtnfVWNxPEoe6qtXiD@JAmLgcZxU6f06GmKGdQ7SAOnhy3U@9xRKbBB8oGA8rRfnP31Au4zLuVE5C3HiAVByyhSZPDWVjY4MdQyNh958dfLr/jCH@@/fJG0mEINgxHn79sx/3@KcMAuM0wXeY3BENCGTcQ4gegA9OhS8OriPNqeuO13@NiT4dQMfDw28WhB9dEQT6pAW02zOyK3fF5liSzADxr0f5JuGCjKgJBebPcVIczbu5Hjs1PRMPpyMOfbS2ttzYcR8NWRiU2S5@ago/aKXTdzUA9ak94RaNfLsmMWhpcshy0myTkOVf4RAjEePbG9DYOwbICsyzTRh5JhX2JbREnHiucOMFklSPX0sSgK6QS8LxJRLxmnk2T2m6yttf@yfKoMrAPQH3d3z3LHMP3n7Ff@uD@1e5@4WCDe26ObcFLlGE0ASjXwKOSEh/pH3kC1s2NxixIBxanQv4KjNHUE2nRHWMznPgdwnY8QJOovEpVBo0N6gx31AEz89wWwm0AVlRFGxSKL/KtE3fmPE9c1dsQRbyhZyqAJLSaQCQjLcP8DAwB5hMVqCbCKfmuPYSZKLt7W0mohJr1ApVXrPKpv0iK74MEd2EuMLZEJFrMEgDSRYpIKzuJ4PBJ6UmMSlyr7gaR8bVc2BUonAcvfDd9gkhsgQQi9PIQGvgM/wY28SdBzZNO/j5ssiHPTZ9QJIKYxK5kqLgm1h44kyg@UAnXXy6h5tYwD2jfAREY4Ee/0QhmRLF9ihf71mLk8HBF0T8viYjD@Cgspmrg2m0bsXPEMQRgqiIq5pv4wVrTpp2S@Ftk0Ez/eGKxmyD@5eVwZo2y8u9e92QZOKqGUgkFrt7ZDuorT@AwrCEpmhZRS0kF0XK5VYWyS@Rnw0UB63VXEB2wKaAZXQN80tn7O3u7R98fPj06JqxRIoZvxoN@H59O9WU5HSjFTri0WItV8m9B8rR43sPgopYIF2IcGNg/H5J1JtKspiEQ5CLQx1Xi7YKw6ulW4/xZ/zY91V8s9pNqFGia3iomffIlzZWSw/oeNTVzLXSKmrl8zehtICnREDv8bOt11BNJM8vG63tetOOxa@3hBUd4UVM3sJOAK6mt7WpYGO/XjgsWPjx0GP8gpgX7YvZ1X1R3MyiLS48Wj9xThbWynyPSECkvEE2wCIFWQmiru19h1xGX9jU0/jHTbkRr6iJogjChcxNFI@AOg6@k4pcZGER1DeGOQQtzzI7QmAaihvFDGz3hfYwuVmnRFLwvyvBM074X06dVWYy7aJKJJHbEaw0u8m@ZgAvKUCHRunu6RSUn6fOmNsZp9Xy@0bgeuYA@wXdn7Rrg308HUG8Pj2eGbRyAZxbgsRAyXiIKpelgEv45jVnKTRgCvk10MimX3B51MsnZkl5aMx65gB4eyKZBo72oaq2WGiCEwtNJjftuEh1tqiFG7viR3hiOUr297LDOlsgoDd0GbR3Y5aIn8WTlRbkj/7xs89O40lxVVsie7C@gdTeVcOwIfpF9WZOok/83hlYXV3FLcrl61wC/K4C5gbKgo8clcvy0BPoo3U1lNyPJu4jcIIYkeiP9DFLTG1u3E1m9JpoJuw0Wb2S6txwpM1SKVKo4EEBMqOUfXLx8Tuh23OWUGrQCNDXs3v4eG2OWUOV5Ra4KZMk28SPj@2BxIXmDpMC6MCQpEJga9iEQM0AjHgnkXkDhzQYDnHhQSbyVgTTt5hogtdBmlCpWf0Oi3xMbllyFMvlil@hy1yxzKD1XWeHsgJgr/G5QK4H6vp2X4BmoP7KQmzByK9zvBjlG@OIPPQNxgA6sYix18CODANYC1Os3aGLv8S@DX0F5INK5fnxg3YpqYgsNDwzcM0eLkBwe@Whiud/YQa6qbIUNV7lGt1HmAxN/LW5ZRu0NPeAOox4haXGomS4@j3oRdtU1RtbvZ/QrwWImcMBwD@g1w7AoVnGYMZoRdhqZv@zn@EXp8XEpqqetN3TVDyfqcJNreZZnn242ZSkzUamdndTBy1q8mrWBJ1c2crdPzWG/c7BQGmKIsuynKJsnZ/HH2w9NV9ohVezy6xaenUyVgsN@dWsJZZq6ZMWe/r08zftN0lxdjp/JTYTGn35eO/wQlRzqOjHKmV2vlPIxk7K@AFRpuv5EzYDvZWdsNdwnfQZ/pP7dS/i1tHd6b@mDy/FRRZrNvFz0WJRVJRGvAX/pO6/hIsr/o26XJd3Wm/eJBu6PpnNmWmaY6/Xg58zBAlSSx4xyPcOcHqKr7AmPUmBoms06y/mEfQ83OoantaU77bRh6xFznaNwWC6r8/N6YPJ4y8@C67neL1@tmJCopVKJSSpcdW70tbzMaZltD/7ycZl@vxpe/vPvjlSjA18HOLjO5eP0X2k5j/c2Pjw3r1cLq1pGnc//eLp13d3d3P30/mnjfxOTspsbP/pn2xsaNq2pmy0PE9txRsnJ5@LWiYnyn/2o3j76dOveV49@39@401dxVsRbqesCHwCrixTwYn3EvxUlLHe9Yq9jkErV2Nz@mvHAv/zDabWd4r/5XuHr2KTWF1TPnPhOYm9ihVKMe4EB7xlg7fTWD22jdEKl7G5UqvVwFn8L/8W0tc/BjgYMt@GWz0fwCrMY3WpRkkuYvUCOFRNg3z/7298I4IhZxM1EuOC6y5rwCXmipq404Jri65tAQ36SRlFCeLZk@HEcJhauqPewRcTXuBhG2gZ3Zg0Y/g5XnZ4l7FnjVQq1ZLbElzyC5wjUlRVa6rqHeAG0odbtZq0xbjFwmw2fwetLidpRmvgwIBp3GGf/UNcsVWe1Z8b3DMhVti4@/J@vQ6FytazW/UUXX5Pok5VLImOc1dkafYyDipIo/XyEe85rC5mSpqYTqd5d5ohqaTZoiXhxe@xWOiDXZZd9VtKAlF839j7x4vt4/Xn/9uff//Pv0d/36fff0CLh3bP7CtbEOkUukQdrruVSrdeF@uueN7E9zq0o0ylVCkp7ctmYgs4UOsZUzMfXcTz2fgRQ/YPAwBrJik1XJRt3c8e3@uxhXed@9Sjfn4Aj0wezC8FOZaoRu6QatfiwdDq7w2VGqf1loQCUU1qqIV8S@KpAizrZda4C9UkasWy2Kpree0Qqk4VecUNNz3mxEAzLAR09PGtL8pWD0MWb/WoV6weJKsv4rxvvADduhBrNJSWQQNC4MfublQ2SpVCRVPaoef1i1WvexmG8dSLncbCi1MntiBoLGyaV/2CqghfWNCC2fvEA8kowsFm4RVxXr3asxsvmt@HawP@6B@u8BXvG@Tje1OU69cGq6hbWlbJf1jY19j7XQKME6zb6XRedzsoBugdvaurE32qz/S5PulMO7MOyFBsCj/sNYzJUiybVzdjd9jaIgmxN40N9oxzoRZLBVczdev1XJbbvpMcDv4kyZnFhNg/wFVXNZVtwfiUgRsIZeQEnRn/VFVgsXO4Wm@2Gm@2oIPWU9vEHVt1yccSHnL7bislXV42wF2t@v/b9dBZpYu7oHCty1Rq@0UdRI8X9UYKQL7wQcoSI6Byu97appAwMz83P3i7BcKLlNpubNecPfpBErikeM6JF5y7LQC8vYTs3bspGVx3AUB9E/pjMpXalKQNHBsb/lgBkVv1VFAqxCEB0sL5@c/5A0UPuuzl9mX9srF9ebm9Df/bdL/0n@B7uX3tnx6La02cRXgLWUuzodSbStNnFC14l5U6@shKExx1eEK8RlYrtRrogEtu/bf5L6cX99AHUW7JgLUQ22JbMbS/l41tCbGXb7/6X/DXfPvV76O8yODPqAixc@zWyhZqm2WudMKN2Y9t9phfNrjxF7yiD3o8rqOnzW82LkgpykuZVficf0ItFZIyDsBtp9/GI/0yewlRUXCDcYmJWqkgtlPqXGOxbbFQpJHpF69d8Xj8H73UysU4n57Bk@gvPc97HMFtgR1ErmoZVVIv6tzYOv8uxi@uuv7RL667hNhFmRkVoErXY5weQgyaT0ySYJSqb49wpzKuj0ioip7WPpee70o4d6JPaPWry@cFagf7tXK5zpd2Np9SV9m6vwV3Ff73N6AUrNmHuM1@rTsCqbfZz@a1JhrmjkmdV/j36DX@seMu/j17hX/s@DX@PZvgH3vcwb/jV/i328G/4xH@3XuFf49f49/zAf41fyGbVavi5jkRJqWW1cvNmUgEqsZ26s1fmLjzimXYDbPX8r85k82VWTLW/AVjhl8er3DPfvyn3/3mN@O1WlyK05c8cqrjMjVZBdpDibx49W5ciNXYprqpZqxMN6N21A44TJZxWWaYGao9UE7aKssYLDPPzFlm5Kg9cBnwlwGXmemzzIBl7IwNESEUXJN2ZoKuPjwG8NcHQC78mbjxrqNmugwyslBQo48AInhwXbSbQoPFmfjSAP1SVuWMXDBb@OmUhvjyZVPZamnlEpOxScntxstmvIW2tLVyjnXmxkbzZZvFPNBQqzGl2VQ4TaC4RLLLy3Z7/8n9dlvBcab52Dlc/B8ejqKvN/6PDp3Hh87Igf/Dw0PoG0Y9dTcFHPju3RpwZP@xE6tXd5oV4usBb48p2zvNelZCdyEF7FpDv9R7XguI8KxvNIX4WQKVizPUL6qfnVVPq@Q@C17B0a4uIgTRuMN/wnUGY1igb5zBdXqGDnpD59lnzdDFHcpnZ@D1GQPNKvwHDS76@l/h3/xv6//xc5ZkiUYrmTi/3E7QlcS/ZPL88vzSv9eTiYT/ktiGP/SAd0xyfllHJ0U6B1cjkWwlLy@5H9wTyW0OsA7ZbNcp7SIe8P1YmCVly2@J/7pPyNq/mvEqA45D2nM@Q/0oJlaZvtg402zOMplktRN8FgCXgfUL2p2QrNI34TY7DbX1pz@iTz/sJClSPletqluMv2g5rVrNBW/FUrVaCl42E4ny9aue2VELoGDkcslktQovOwHYDLxC2gZ7k2I11oR7684dnklJu7jwywGZBxnkITfD07s@Uz0/OKSPJQBHycfwKyWcgyQy9KkV/JxXXKyId@4k/M@E7@wm79zRypmLi9BnPAYvdcmr3e6ZbruN/tmLC7Et0v6Wch7eM6WLCzVTTqnxpOMmnuB34CCrhKSyD7U65VoGVq3lihDsI5Df3i7k6vVCDnwKpXgS18obiH4L8I2L8aoYO6cyqKUiZ3xiFb1XzSEx6Ms4ArDzyxhVKMvlkwlgpUkQ8i5j@OeKTdEfW/L5JJDoUuQx1XKZR02yXCFRSpX9v9oGqN0gxfA/FMWyqdxWcesuCLX4563UKZAnV8@NmnpZOzcqOG1@We36n9ZFywPGnTvZMtCqlKk2hXb7/u7xbrtdE0URJSG4oSdxdwENMrjxBpEgX25x0lSqd6m@1VKeQcXyOFIcRghWAuor2lZeLSG1BLOPhkWAJALpQmyDbQgaPfEmlDnlNsAT9BXIvAcX67EOG@DFBjj7yUxm0cUsxsPp3u2GkRx@@aHhK6XFK/QxwkvwW2@Wt1UYsZ8@2t3bP05r2xKLaQ9299La0fN7MRVf84t3Cs7i@7P93fuHzyHB00f7u0f7Hx18uv/8Kfh77GxxBUzfvy@eUdeK9zP2mfCl@1o3DN2YGkb7bDo9e8W@NM22CZVpTaFQzsBlntGGsoz1Rbmq8Ouanv7ll7o7pou9/eG33/7wv3v7O999@zvffvs73//pV9//Nvx@DL/v8ud3/005j/effvXPfvftb/8OeP4H@P0R/H7y069@4xv8R@9/DL//FPH7Y/8Xicd/AsD6lZ9@9b0f/fSrX/0B/P6l//vB9d@v/WT17/vfWv/DdN/73ZvjfPffwu/3OKwg7nd/m/vh81r83@bxfvUHb//Fv@P/f@r/ofN33v6LP8ab//JPf/Cn/@ntN/@9ppX@9F@//db33n7rm2@/9Z233/rH2tvf@NdqJnr73bff/4O/@sPf@6s//B/p/8d0/713@X/7g3/6F//rX/zvf/GH/u8n8Pt34PrJX/x76Cp/@wc/xP/v/cHf/tEP8f9//ld/@we//re/8j@R4ze54//5l/@G3//61/7j3/zWd/7qJ9/4m1//yd/85h/81f/xq//Xb/zHv/7vf/@v/8k30fM3f/JXf/Qrf/nNb//lt/75X37zqzX3b994/@od/L/6B/B5dzzfBc67lOt9fb76ufD5@1BjkQu0E2jdv/z2N34JGvi/YOztt3@MZ3bgt@b/x5pKcX7M3/4/4NCulxlDMuCC36@//fZ3kUT/A5AI/kN6fSd8WQrhL99ZvABZf2tFol/@6Vf//Ef0FjMqdVqWwbG7pJVSW6DfbJXL/vjtr9hAkl9ahhYC8HP6DnKopbDvIG97@8NvvP3RP377w998@8NfwcFbypXTu2lJvWW5CyLm3yEeRiy8SzyM@Dnmn6I5NCn1Obyxz/3Azz//XGhfKHg47O4F@H5OXvxiPAgPj/lBQRj642kydsGibt@Z8Z2bvm@YM2ONly9buKAKfph7imSPrUA0ymfZLBVMSbNZMDWNkWZbfJYa7@SLwTMBb4v/hXMmsNRiMhs/ZhdO6VJOPJqfBXcKecgmNZtF5sRJ7iEMuQ8tBFO@uTLDEsxmqRkoweCAHFIQdA/E8VothQlrHB945ajVS4xQSaVqUG5MzdOk2yUEMbtHUCBlLfWMtbdqM54whfDqATlSAno9E1VNTJVq9yHD2uw@Q1gInMC@fFmrl2qzOoJ7w@mRmqXuEU4IrJaa1d/Ae41gQjohdv8NoFKqpVL1EmaIheTVk27zSspT4ajsKZby6wCeuJ9/5y5jH4pqSWxzgREJxmPjPbWIjREhOoQ3U1t@ceg/cNJviwi@QVn5uTAevkOy6Q4XVzECwJUkWZYZ/HCFfYfdheAZB5WibOGR4hBS1CKoBYQeDCeDUkKK6jdFL5B/rLb13hcCw8Jsbm4KsbqYFQ9lIp2iMPekQocbcL8fqhcVJhbKInobdNIjwAXSVyn/zTiunMUZB8w@TPHf3btb7EMoJj0XfgKTUlkn58Q4lO1UStQAft1JCS9ALRGgnRKgC0Ge1WilLiWk04zJtRiGscPDQx8J8nhRE1LQzLWsiu@4XjSdTmOQQpbTcjrtP2V6kofsO2QK9Z/yJhKXvpjMNC1XBe2pytCLRVUdFVRg9Hzz5g3UCm2gqhyAFsr8vVRarkSB4MFtZFjWPDgRpOXKAtfMmVrIMZag2VS4kiwpsATbSgp82z1HIrgSca1UilM8oL6c2Aq21hVUag44kxqrI6LBxVXCUj4ZBO4dsr3Dx4/3nxyPWy0mGPQFaKM9dp2u4XkJDNt9cp8fudDKhWSs0UDQxxUNGYywX8kQMz64/@zgqMJ4of0qSBBiVVo49YtZVoXYePzZdszfWiTiR8wc8QjvlUXZElo5C0ljdSHWNVCzwBXxKm0pqQqPvcE9ZwbKfVoU02oBNbskzR8z4evOlKGJTW6PA/oUHsSQt7eJAkL9XKK1CXRCbRWEet3flMdUoX60fwwJjg@ZqmVkof45m8mYoXQp1K2aZdiDyXATd7eJzYwYKdNmI5PGPy2bhbuaK6TVfLG1sWGdS5hnk6rtHLcpXsLruYTF@AAuJnwgsA/ACy7IA/ceMn/j58Fh1d99h8asEnwLnqjmoZslBZy05uCE8eICRKF1L6/0CLGNL76YsHod9Gvp4IEQA24xZMEGNMnsyUOZqrk3dQ0KHTDWMz818et0cs/0xpY@h64D1IhdXl72AdLBA6bVNXrlKXp4v@ySTwfclzNdiNmVSu2NmisK2kml8iaraQJ4CFsK7nDbgAZAGwW2FP5X9SCTbLakAKdSRREe2WxWwIliQagYAqPdIG8ytZrE22A2p9JmEAE/eKDPalp4@XFnHy7iZjM8LoZAABtMXJYJwoo8zH8rCPQGRMPtb/R53arfOTN37mRxEiOby4SzFVRidgl1s5nNZZHiwv9/RS9awdke17MZdVsZg1MHZ25b0cHZAWd@W@mA0wRneVsxwTmtZ9XMtjKtC0zY5lYtGRrNqIkTY4ZGdLmfWPcMqy/jGaKaSBlo4rZvJboeJKz3aj2nS5/IrvZkEz9VjkdceYJcTqw6Ntpbq6HlBToUzBLJc2FQO6ODuIJRG8howsO1dUvoyR2nN5e9ydzC0ziW49biIBXGg4AFdAPEEZwC28lmc5UGa8ljZ7wjaPliqqFmYBzBn1pKa@kNY6dYrPTkrmXo7k6@ki@le3jQx1/W2slnKgP588ePHk4m42cGnf7ZyZUhARq9QvM0O6VKPt9qNEQx1aBsWviBX86lpI0N6NqG3pPgiYtenqSVWpC4Z7q1Wjy@k1U1Sa1kM6VLYUE4pDmWsC5g0hSWLI10P/cZQcV2bOA5lbSeNs@JCpV@v3@5dZ5avAj6ucTfgD6Xkp7unIevVSkSr8KmaclcBIKP3gdyn/vreRVRy5fEaqO6eC8WxGrrUrg7Mnqmjod@mpnz66kKwJs51Bhk1GTCZcV1nEmlY/Qd11hEzKqFICJH6HqEnHgZZtfMYI7n17MrRCLNzq9DyeXFyzBVgJZweQl058SGfsEtltZpb2xDLeda@8CIGq3twJYp1k3sxQtdr9ehks9zRS2Xz@W1bKGQL2ow4JRzhXwJulmmkMlrGgDIlUvl4iW0aCGm61K9ltWygqZJWlbKqpKaxf9bHBr@v3t8Df41vEOqrCYco0GQJzCSwehrs0doWGDisGMHPy0zYPeM7poYe0OddhHvuY7n/T3i3NPtEx503@RWOMOghzp@X8sbmZPhmhjPxyO0JWK4/2AQ9kcdQBBZE49wD26u5TirIhTZ86drSvk4tHsNxOCGryH6s4OPHh5Hnsf7u3sPhQK7d/jk/pVH3o@UZ4/2HxyHr0UeGiTNhyC@vv/o0dVX/5E7fP6sP3Vc/AkPDp/nFrfQCw@pCjm4liOF3gTEv@EryXowyINulC8GDlXAow13QF@94zvzhYUzg87P@Alc0wu32vPD2BXhODiWqzPkeh2DdbnJGFSgyZybL16rxbIgjJntnLFihvUcy9LxY@H9DfAc6njE0EAZ06Jv3WPWZ45r9c7MnrEhPMbTjGUVP8yMSAgPAcho2iXzASBfoHHQHn7GG5eMOtbUYNMxW@sJD/RCp2sOhjAenjlBBKGj6wx@73tBeiN6TW72mPA8yO9aiHU9uhATRHFPFB/qE/1urNSoeq1xPVOp3LmjPnXFclb0Bsb@DJosew5dSHfn6ZI4kcUHTG7HBrjUYBXUnDOu63VQDRogSJc1GEl3cppRL2Xyf/1bP/67P/n1QU3damb2Mts7jx/lK8AeQbZkJD76IqZMyoZWLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLg55WLIOonlFLaqGUL6vpUq4MQkGuDKH5ctEXUJVAIlW2KgDW7uK3grdJX5GHoJjwVUL2OqEnWUwP36dMNCCNKKBqOKET21tmDcYzpmZYtsgAos66LPbgwV7mwQNRvIcvuJNiLyOKPXzJlzKZ4j1RNChkr4QCjujwNCW0uiZO@Esmcw8IPeUA0GC5KA7xZb@Ak1yiaOLL3u6DB5hPH180TA/RTngIf7GClyJEs/EF5GYC8CqEBtF2eT45QnQfXzBLDHnAQ/YgTBQ/CtDBkGc8GgfwMCjp7q4oHvCX3V0M2aNi5zmin@DLLl2i6MILtH5RHIBj4EK/E8UOOLEPiGIXXN25Dn74XWa0aW1PdFGcc/IggURxRrH17okotgN/zOZTH5s8UrdCLyov9V16KeOfKGoB0hgtG75kRTEXvuSgbA8ffqoPJz1jwK@5y59dKOnDh1ndnE33H3Q@@qgzGHTc@e7@R88waG/vIQgH86nbGXT8hJ02XA6k2nuo6Sej@dULSn3Qbld0a2XQJ@12TrevBLXnbQMxhFSvADP/GmBGo/YeBO09bN/VVy3uEsA2dv8RPDt43RvB857e4UHBRUH0nHU6YhWbv6I0EwKK77gsi93xBNipnR7pXdep4vusxjJpVPbnjUKmVaUANgIxPFO9xPB@Au86zsgkz@eNWS3Tqs1qRY3vDuonxOZMy5tiemO0o5bzlQ19R9VyqVkFjUY4/TiLS@oOS6h3tl6zxJPkjgYiudjc2ZHEhtra0dRSpVB8sTUVxWQF7zvZYgUiZuIZxvCWbBRbO8V8JEmxmNIVrVIsJquXQJQJDOodnClpJxJnhn6STCK6qLdDEaisbE7lNKv9xCw9q3G82DxZndXUKrflyjLXYPXQcPi0O3FcDnEA4GY7mQquiydEtVwSIX9FSSSTIdMDLVpY7Lz87GvHJ8fHn0MYE@r@jMJT/qXzqv/60cM9@eAweEOT3/IDVIQcV95DrrUUwi1SB17HoBLID2EcBfUq8MPDea5jyfu0eQ20qSAgMOQq@@Y35eOHS3COhs4ZzxltG1TJhpvdNRhaRDd7TK/VwaX3WIKwYnryjEbwdr1ea9dGdPwfihik@oSRufAFmAOP4x5aXKDk53hgzQ9o1zKX1U5tFpsBnHaNSerLkdN7qaW61R4aQr9Xu4eJq214dqpGzXBdxxVjYrW/Y9cYm9qe3jeeGi7aEjk43AR5Ak@xJfrMSG6y5j7G3kPF4VKqu8xeYPZkOkqAZN5JLntFXpE0ia8FRT6nY5W4b@Ky2q@xxItk9RW8upss0ZPvJXdy1V7iHmsnwSfzsv@yzzRWyFXpC8UJhATdiGiDZdaTtfonIAJxwCeVCiDi1/EJwMScAKzZowA9OTYvq92axRISm7EkkSdXHdQamPoCb9uSKLYkqXHREuqS9JlQh55ancf0mjft0NczWKajaplCdQZ@ajFXHULF6i9mVbc2nrpG1YJXf3qNnx7Vq0BOoBqAeX2RePtL30huS/ka96sSqAsLpI623K7Nqjba44MmUcvWICDVyGXSoEzDrZiG0V4rpNVCOpvOpaUi@sJQn86nwRMUHBAtElZCZExMZ2YZWU2rhppOZF6avZfJ9EkCRBYiGUumJ86@PR0x8IFKwlZJr/DUWTKlbVkMasFh@rZEzRR4RRULBjQfsrGZHiKoZ4ZuUYpkUmLZrYS1mcA4m8fT8X6jVansz8Zfg6CE9GqnkCpmUq@TyWpiI1nzjFdCvSrUka9Qqccb0Gb9mUfmTUcNqGNwqUWt0mh0sIjFTDqbyULpzPbFYFusi610ZqOgQhVdMmIYjHOM6GQcyjoLv3EbBW/LgKpTy1pVkGlmLFvSpLKS38pn@OwcTymMfcaGlGSJphiclE7E40UtHk/Gq7gusCH6E8HAzYiTxYGtxu@oOyKIYWJFLGsYYcEU6TBsJsAOBLFLAechWK4sxM6Fy/PLbdCKFdpSCXIj2yCXJNfvCrEKY8AYm75tJmWDsffdqZnarr/gzybuwQe4AhnOBTmUdlAZJmpi7FM897/D4oCY7o4ampZtNbQiDGXAHIOooI9XcSkkhrv85TpQ2DsH/LZTdTwy9wmbz/WUFMzN32FskNoUqMyxq8ueu7XdwbPdYDfY7h5O9zZB1MZNYrHzeCx@CX9C7C6d09P4OT0Wi5zU49P9vxC/G4vH4zivDoR6EyMewfbOg4mwCn7HLaFXOEdotJJvnpjWeSkr8fkJYFGXl7FNBRc9/fWKbK6QLFNNBeelPnmpQSOJ2U7gASoSTiXB8JXP4xx2THk59r7QStnHB4f2ffeBwfjxqVKuLdZjLKNKeAqpWvF982J740SFNpIVsyfpGLsbo73sYrmkiRr3qMbYiRRXK/zI1fio/KL4ovTi8fPD54cPhFhz42LDweUKFu6me2N//DWIGM/m4ow1a7FZLedvxVbrdUnd1tA8WpFVgP331YKUuajzZl6ngIIGIW9/6Qe52XYJ3rWMCu@alk9p9bq6pbFkbPz2q99HSzfn@5/uPmJxnOT@uz/5kVb8uz/5V7QPLH5JE99athiDmOhUC8XY@fn4/PwSLh6Wj7ViHKlcMQluvgijxuqKqmVt266yiqLrW8VUTrtrVxU/rlpUkzFPivnLScV8zLvwg7RMCYKC9R7yEgtYJbH9Z2ZeU@9u70BxdrI5rboBzUgNj3uy8G/b8MoxIVZ6/PKCMXjp1nuDgamRS1FY5Y3Ett9I2@wNrrW8kTbYy1od1@xVPCQarEVs4aE5XI@L11PKVpyBdsTqjcvqZStFyxmgSL4wjC27eaUTNDfw1MSy15YNf8aWR3@YKPDw4DV4M7a@9MTEVlJRer3QnNq2wfJ1aBVbCuC2FSxI8D9Jaibf/tJvaFrh7/7k1y7aF@3PNdAny@WCqsV@9rPtqT31jF79Z5DwBhMmgU5IqzloawQdoS7JuMVQ008VOuQuqLFTG@VmHj/QLFGXRJnDHNhGjzRL4RTlJKrINrei10tQtC20cJAmuZusViWrghDKpyRXu4NummCwLbQkCT1dOBc@wCAYjBnI5lXhgwUo8BjB8Ot02541dcd0xiRB6dRWmt2BJJDDB2igcIMsM/icXALup2xdT8pR9ohqJFOxkeF5aO4QBiHhA0jim9u15mysoxERjGnaMHTIGIXwpIBeA/JuQd4WT9Am3wSVnkdIM44dT2SD7C18AMIEUcEEGYOZ2xChCmzpAyAAlCHhAzZbbJtlk@zcTKWqC1uKl7hZHq096oEBAwGTIbQeGswIElcxHniBzI8feMR24dcwiHcRzwAIh8HX1mugNWByekOhjSyMvDMogEXWvBJUNHbnzgKrWs3sJRmVCOGfmGOc9qJ6sFfjCsACjevDXkVMM7RSWQ18w2YHFE8RutDqJG6eshpJykR8vRQE@H/nRost8kpVUUAVC@DXF@8VXSAZJEay8zrssu0aU7VikoXIdwH3LiFF58hDNbI5@1DWPg8CLwHDn8WCz6cAizqOTiX67faqBQsGg@gUv12Bdsw4M/AtT3BLZcjqDiZB6jAVFMW0KHbfdEHBoUX/wEhiIqsmMdnCqCThQfvatRzD7eX5JD4oFcZm8NTR2J@fzwYZKeo6UKHe2LHJOiBZL8It/dAigEf5htU42lP7DL915NcNJY5i5JFRNWz5iDFZO6SPRFNaXHXvuKAHB7RJM2Mgs@6ox7QyS1BDIwNwdgguSYkI4Q5Iy0jjjmWMAKUjw6BDX15FUQYgbE07ZAXvsQntavjAhPHG9hT/e9zKmXliKsf4rQbJ6ePZMG5TJIbyGXY/vsDvW5yzHOeEWeaJwWeIE0sWWTwG@gKIvGmg7OIHhK3gzhEtm8YJCzXNY8GvCI8id5bSkbQbiXny@jOrbiTaWKMXNPiYLn5r@1S3I/Sl60LwVWRv7gU2ncgyEbzLIcs1fGsutTjaaQjNFAm@daoaGUaSceVhnACFNbDqhE5h7BqnDJVdAccYYJrdwD4K9mIo7Qc0AFDfg56Fxh4nbgWt@gAmbi/Rha7nM3ibfciymoARuckt3zwWwMCqry1DhzBIiuXwJj2oGJmm25GvQO8c9SAM7Un4zQ/TB60b3WSIc9G82YYPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wd2J6p6BsQWAAMV2CykRBTADYlJkUOOkx/NTlv7QLxkgq7DinNEIJPaoBCooKOLIc@jb74KJEAAfd0j1uu901Bnp2dyWSfdOqasuHhh3o8x9YtZTwwQaJ2lIkxGvufRDXxU9g@3IVL4t/nksfD8c4MRdda@c6cPwWh79X8/TeJeN@L4@B4it@hGYzIlhkaEfOoQT0w6RtW3YS/HYi3P62VPg/aXwXbn1SKXyIQxhDMLD1Pd9MALN3pnqT7Z72qH3BKHRKAQy0agSdaDXaDl5EXuMxxP4zhTJCPhkEd64TWUgGSyGd2F1nzEgYx58Gr/z42Z5DINs7Yruvq8wSFJzE2NuDEnMQeNodhn0LACcMMO@cmbM1ZY95aSj4Lk8OgFu4kcNFQmXB@M1BuzxjDZzx8BuEzHj5bZBpk25i1uEiGXpdYHGz1aN8yiIlg5kGcS277dxFCkEH6ZioHgTHnS36X8OvWKHVAb/4G9VgLGga0iTEQ3EgojRfNRrNle8bZViulDKCxi0QIqHEA3WgRTc96oRupb51aY8db8rLRrCmMSj7e6NUd@q2BtxUsY1hB1DA4vUy0RDkY@VseuEDgFxggoBwGgSga7E4SZrIa2s@mQGg4DXFBY45Yw0emRdKXH@T7gbjESc8JGwXUigBC/7BIgCaEsKDn8M@yBdzhM9eBOEFcib4kNUKLaPFWHCh5patwXlOlSopgJUkBmkB2FFdrV4sShENVNK4ERYp56dd/FP2N90a/D/1iNfbUYPmAURWiXQU3G4II4XcXoiqr1yL1ChgoW7pluDBy7XP51B@tIZstJVAzeD5YBO8MvzWfiFR@N8nrh440irZYCZvCvFaDIs5rvFvyfhGQlBM8TOb5yeZBQ/DTcwYCMDIrkxl@slk02axW44yDzdYkO4sgOSMkZzwJjz1bg2TLTwba00EwvGD1tEA6xd2QIsBT@TAKYtBYZPjBeVwM/xKtNeJqgp/ngudQK/DbEIrY2M66rZW5NyJIR5jWFQDYEK8B6PEvvFaEqwxPlcK3kEdxUgY8ir/5zYDzCmhgxIKr3KJxImxkpAODwC@maByAviumGoKo0rww/mX4T0wHnsFPve6ZWY6pLntm0lf@/kE8W0jZSAeNSB9qJocMGTWZ57ZvCjQqc8TwY@hDB6S6zpnDEiuEbfBXpn5SpWM5HWWk46YW/O4j95XH82SgP@CaCrs7dib6xMnlKlxpMqnZrcqf6wzmwHbwczERq@Yg6/Ucw7PjE6jUrjOwTc9IMzQ4eWL4aofhf2ZBiMrJvtPxBMGf0eRqLILm7QpF3XYbv0TdbidwB2GyEu6Kpg2F2DzjcQH1X3BF0gN78oEejhNO50ujO0neDhNN9PvJjs3uSeJw7Afi7OsuAx7WBfkfQocgwTDPWWiOZP4bRenOJEGfShk6I2cAUt/UkwVMfQX8wQI2IqSPx4RLmumo0lYiH2qgXpLopvWkn/ST907KPtESejJMry0DWCJGmrlXaYyUdVdk116bHU8W5Hf0/vgeRfE9uhlf0sKv4sxV8xoPfL@ss4kFBIi4QCN7OxpYdOBbvWvoLKESeqNcxRO8M4o92jTWQ0x3IequH13uQ/tIh28evIWIf7qO/jdXYJB8/12rT4duz47mwG9GuBkyQV/48oLF0QREP0gi77meXdi0779jXhAXP674AEUIEGOJcdlouRg65hjUbi@cLg4A39LmcZ/WtXZPm7dqPHAFTu5pmp1o66vofrtnWPrc6CX8mOkI3KDEz0BhI371bgVHRkdMz@G6XgLGrmQYCsM4Ep1HqqxpMnr6NJlc36x4FDNsPTRTThgerKcfhl9jzTjFV@Oz1aAHxOMxnI49NXH6czwfz7lxfIt/3snno3z84TWJ9hluJwjQgY@eanqRbfIm9vksERbpHUaEMK68XGS0XR1ARNNG1@vw/Uh0e0mhciOJakEtC8ufhVld4@ZNNR5pFUGb5KtM79Ykb2t079zmIk2NA1uwsL33G0KuQcb9HN1uIgqR@9xYY459jSegH83T2WtGlfYKhhqmJE43MUndJvkiKaBmfABPnHD6FJ4IcGBM2rxBBWXDOS3/i4mMQkb6OCK1@D4gpAOUCBU5yX00IrGEwA3Rzy/DPLtr8@xey7O7lGfYA5azjEQSuktZ@rWA1XNTFVhGf7KGO2MQ6s7wuIltw2U7uouzFedxM14x0yx@Gq8AQ44b8cp@AphyvBev3CeHF68ckeMkXvkEHIu@Fb@IV4JugRFceCXHXfT3WTi@d@OVvUTyUpjoJ4YX5CvHK2GdQpwd/koUAVJguUFqxCU22/GLOXENGNhIqEwzbDFeGtUnmodJ0y8D//xDT/QJGAzEOc4tisxSTF0aNCIjBs8Hho3gEwMrenLFH833Dx/QfqgwCmaTAh0vmobAgxgeiy8zI44YhtKKBjwBQeSbldUYschI9o7o@LlDC6VKXs6fqCeTPNBLUHgDIrcWmdDXvfz0QX0tg@AV@G54YuJ1eF5DJ8iOMMI12eQKtJCoL@M3FArrehkXv/ajNURz3cuRAFspiMJricBGeDrIcLQ4h5mNnfFyI6FQ3HpvRtPQpBzvlNh6ryQjruD3zDXB5O2XDBlDtPMnbypOJB2itsSCMLCRafFeFo4LxIsxaMHrIpIq73yAQoTnQA83uif05bT7vpPicXaTprFi3TAUpOVZEudaZpOQWEZ7U1N9wnMPldd9tEL1fuprkHKGcy0JBBBJGebC@avzHvK7w@X3QKAOiHAlg1WC9eqh9Lp4feMoewVza5Ht9QrEwDS7n1wpHIU5LEgO2kFEMr@prV0T8XHLBxfyeaYh9CvSfkC2UCe4hW5XdQsOC6UE93TZ80QDzxNtPaGuSyTWqRwILTLm5MPhBQ8xXRTtZlx5wVdVMYbQ/LZuvXcFu8sVHK08hEcFcK@QnPdyd2rTLpdF3wa2zX2QpaoVxhk5LZeG1bzwBHZPS7fhsi14HLaf3T988ujrMOgWi8WkP0b/v91961YbyZLub@op0hJuVKZUkrDBGCFsAcLW3hg8XOz2AawupBKoW7dWCYN86TUzP84LnPk/j3BeZd5hfp2n2Ce@iMyqLCGwu3ufs2dNr9WmVJUZGRkZGRmZGZdJgh9mLc5a43VcILNxdbwezNi2LHlIb4TLbhzHR5eD0fjBaT9zS5aIsCZlIKBWDPvpOe5qWWbJ86m5S/WkrEVRDeuXZBoEKakEVSfAkt3RdB0TQcJx7lGggRj1lujt8W7N5UQ@jUY/6IWNBi9fJturXsUwNOZG3P1b9kHhKhpxxmXJQnXtOBzvQW3vq3evqkfq6FVN7Rxv/VW93z9W76p7R3D1f3O8uVvfUvR/be@wppyU1SUy9mFDSXTdDpsh0rCqpWLxiWLIW4PhRORObsuV94dBT70aNENcU61HQe/Fpfzw@@F4Q2rVaDs6wRlmhzM09jpj2FtwSkHaxkK5abG7ILwBFJU9pz1tD3ve3qDVaXeorIO977ATRsbDTHU7NIIkb43DsydKErIHsukQZwWFBdY1VQ@oPO5uCEwg9lcgMUpIusGWrzTh4v9@NwWPagevDxWiRmzt723Xj@r7e4dqZ/@Afr55X997SfSsHx4d1DeP8YkLvt7fru/Ut6r8QhAo@grhHH6@isb3ouCjOFOl@Qtuvv0hDX/8K33qDQ1eXQfsOBmphas@pE8n6HY@ha2FsnMVQX2BsyZfFajcfPXg5Vta81X4K244zVUw2x9kjiPOaDlfVOvcGk2WDZpvZT1dadnLl1y@j@hNFJLahGUO85DjZ08Z4GzE0@qEKrMFGxWcfUs0CJ7LBjQ19IBgA5QxWKkoTka1sOCtM8gNaq3ZHSB0p7QmRoT6B6q@MKYmZYcppm1lABT@DvU@zoNK5fgF8T29WNLNjkdSQD2OX0gB9UReQBWtw3ZELesSV@P9K4hntSIvfu4Nd/haWD2NX2wGvItd1TjJuPGQBipO5ofYGF1OOSanPJwWlVNBc5WIyyMdV7crEyOURJAkE@UqkW3bqGSGhE0bVw3a7E3yK@MrcQPshIL2OFK5iuurIxgHhf2OJHu76AZ9MYFKTHeY99QqwhBVNrT6ECdJYw@S4YAZEAka03jE9ba1Vhh@bz2quXmrxUDbSHKiUmOC9i0ENm8h8EfAEKB8aqfT5JWKfVkBZtDWrJyLBsSROLf9zS5P7Ny6aoapCtpqK/dz59MnVxPZS@2TjJ0iY0dD9CkckVrJV5ntwYjmOItVTisFKdi8HAzHHRnDXLoHfOPEyxyVxsJGrf1kiKtbAx2mW@wP@laj58TFd7R6Tkz5Pa0yx8vdeSy@knzDxPm0CIvdHdAJzgcfQ@vuzMMl0nWI4xdShPmuHIefkzFjIvqnk8iO3xTSlK5WNrY3T/O//eQhV6mIBUkVbIwO8T8xJtqi6cH3fGywOILepWeayTEXXZ2jtrbB09ISs9wAo33gZYf2dS8a5fibmBvffg8fm@n3/PLLl4rUykMy6fzS0WUukW6eOjFNelznTGkTEEt2ErIk63PmjccwY3n9An41GAXE1elDjmDfPpXBTYsQ07vzqzZJFp1IVw93DN9VG2xRkWQhh7@MPR6FD7nNyuKGW0gMSpRFzpwR0Z6BXHJdyyyF16tb4LbvB0fy@/vBrd6LnSwPvwva9r3Qfhdu@cW7YcmyZMH6frC/3QNWFrc/BJb67t0NWBbJ29BiTo@Z05vPxta097f4062x47lHYLD24gQlBmq1dtXnK2oTETsnFVwbTKIQHR5t1w4OVEb2J1SX5B62DC0tBgH7gXqTWNt2@izs/FhpijfLsfJk3qQs2sx/903mmcS7Q1RoHcTT9IiFRRJuu925EamnVxZWIdj6ngWioVwau89GBkUnGvBX2gMSssmgWR10ZnYzK4tPJ7KNwDXdPNGNbRt@trCWtRvpaUcTG5BtExRcwLNk9vi9E/14zbQjChaiEKHDLdKkab2hfcIhNTykgr6fHsF7hsUMKYzsRcHOGtrB8KuY1rD/PEMxI4kSLrqwJda1cqxRE/143qg5bJCIZSCApaf@KBbN9MGIeH6zbg@omyx6ufQSREomEpa@sLmCqp991UsYUyNeJyuxQm7PtXnG5sRgeYbTWQ27fHehh7CFXpkWD9NNkbS9t6n836cpWSVSLRmaz@yM@UiQV5aXH38L9nQvTPX8n4Uta8i0/Bz3hrS/T0BGk4iP94lz63ue@Z4wwD2kE9N6M2GmKpKqM2NNSfWdFyMbP8JFzoUIGUSPRw7Y6VZddTOF22zosiLZ0LnIrT5YUzjuqMyaW9T/en9zEMjfbO/B729PJhsKwXTwK6zyXw9GUZh45VkhXqxX8IZNvwtHoz4XE3@mHqDk2I3pXmc79rYTg1fpFT7yfZvdk7b2ThKzW8@cNXAjfLzoI@0zTvfK08d7@VLZ7upOfbemHnE0yXbqLDIzyriW7HnQ6d@HAMtgPpfA8sE@fA@jNfqfcPAMSCITe/PlmDbuN3FjipDWfMK5hLRZqJatpenRb0fNoI@gIF7mYaQy3g9UkU9ha/s77qyT9WI5VZ@Qi4b9HNXyMnk/w1XpHQ50ASkNQkYT760FC54axlIS7jUXA9hH4WIrvJHTM7acDAql1eLKM4d71/fGXu/k2Zn3qFnJKFp8g34vuhpdt365GFx@bKuuGv58ftOcfPpVqeUn6jG1tfSDhPQtrVQKHEX1Kf27qp4VmXM1gs85PDHSEPuSn1WpBZXsw8sPlMsPvGleg4fEFJeqRz3DhXCxG1d6JytnlX6lWO6d9M/KcPIbL1bGi6XFHF78QKsoyRi5mT8Zn2FNtU9dw/5HhcCZnAdUu4Yodg2hN6@DUWewW917mTqNgwKAIzBt680H6pLyeQ7WbPA98fvhdU4fk3kKHOtAQXLm2CuoBFd5Pk/GcUyrQ5jRqHikzUY3/O/EdeaK/tVwPOAvJj4iWEt96Xxx5owbU5FPFKjIScdEUYR/AcFJyuRwMSRvJ2JFnS@JulaC76RrgThBTRaHmdNMBj6FQFT7cp2cOZEfBs1LIIEc51@4mlpf54znxGqRz6d4MOUIRuwwUTzDIy5A6M@QbxvQBGvuEbt9ONR9/C7hQd7wGdWY/WTYQN5hTRFfYP6tPrN/E9dfJwII4edE5/L1EafWvEiRFN9BPlxAwLP0xh/XDHCrlEGZQ2cBW9qrJMDZUpxphGY1mej93DXIKbSi/3QP8iX@dasbcXlXijNJ@J5a/4pASx5S/rSBP92kWs6qljfVTGGLFHPfpAZOumh79DqkaTVRW2G3S0gLLeYScuCR/Xt1@4tx@9EJ2jyLkZfv@Vvf86nvvnwXpJJSPi3wSaE1u1Am@zkp91VlkmLerbYqipUXn0a66ZNKkpQt31c28seDRicpvBEPpXBl/GE99SFvffkwY/Tly4NUnZjB4@8n8l3z95Ie@RjLVNkX6fbx19EDFLLxrLY1meJSv9/pPnd0emz9BWyWIWoqJdU5AaIyk6qifTC1OCENDuf8PG03KgmUxZKRODxnMhvrLzK@VjKe56bREC/GWxNrxhyxqMRtLjLhbthhkdrhzw8sEAwTjKbMzN0wlSe68sQCi1IPTLPiBXlrglPXpqd4BX6RX/CPmexp5Ey57OyPc4L5jXRevJvTBGKh@yAzm0xpaQJ3EXmpO3XPKpK0PZmGOFtI7FmnwHGbofhgt3EM/iCWE7agMJLiFt3jL5rSSYGSYd@7hhAfvzp/KzxyXgakYw@74Y2qYpsRsBeWk3JwH4fROEJsKA5xE10Nh13cOrLCd80u1DqsyNIyrlsSiNbK7jt1WPZIeQ9P2iGdKvlqH5CvYSCSfIiuLi7gTAYP2ME1RCtOXDpj36n2J3KgQXPm8ZK4mYcKwTdYAHc7FzYSMnIye0DpaBg0Q98hHS0i7ceRrrY7OnEon6fDbwTRx2hJW3Ocf7rqNH/Zeon73Kel4uOSRbKP@jq46D9@kjhYEZHMhyUEEFwuPXEc6264KXfDeQD01C4W@rfEm@HHsN8PnSqtGFwwIqU1Ckcfw5bvOAdhfAkMuGBl3EzCD3twNWrK4Q4pXQExI7yEI0@uw4jD8Bfrs1wXN/muzHNwaZXcNtNQf@y0QEDjcdIe4HaYLywQJkDogUq9cExEeeSqNEp896xxYd2lh4MoogbinFh3EzEZ@oNxp0kjwydZTpdAyTVI0li/NYUJtdfsBnAO9mchAPeYhAIGAXOVdB8Ojr40/104KN0xc8cemJEpkPQb8Fyh6R6OOiR9EwLzqHA1C3ca4KNX9UN1uL9z9K56UFP0/OZg/219u7atNt/zHTcuyjkar3q1v0vSJb5Nl1vzfXqRqR5SzQx/cKp771XtxzcHtcNDtX@g6q/f7NYJGoE/qO4d1WuHnqrvbe0eb/PtO0FQe/tHarf@un5ExY72PW7VVHOSemp/R72uHWy9op/Vzfpu/eg9t7hTP9pDY7jVr6o31YOj@tbxbvVAvTk@eLN/WFPomLNdP9zardZf17Z9ap/aVLW3tb0jdfiqurs71dH9d3u1A8VGAlYvN2uEZXWTtrBoifu5XT@obR2hQ8nTFhGPENz11OGb2lYdD7Ufa9Sd6sF7TwM9rP3TMRWij2q7@rr6kjrn5L5BFRqXreODGqIlgRKHx5uHR/Wj46Oaerm/v820PqwdvK1v1Q7LytndP2SCHR/WPIVMh9w0wSBq0Xd63jw@rDPd6ntHtGYcv4G9g0uD/I4IQ1hWqeo2ExhmEOgtEWn/4D2ggg48AJ5696pG7w9AU6ZWFVSARcXWkV2MGiQiHtndVHu1l7v1l7W9rRo@7wPMu/phzaUBqx@iQB0GGe@JdajRY@41xonwkkdiVsdwrsfDqeo7qrr9tg7MdWnigMO65hYm29YrTXMfoXqtQ5TOAGcGQc8@WGnffvUxRHDK2ycys89o4ohJW/vbNVqRdWirTPLhmFad1alQSvY3Wmnij/QzFbKmFZ5fXTQ6/fYAPqZxNTn46EUXHvL3uEh@curck8ZKn69whWy20XhbbdBG97DRcL3vqZlC41s19DH4faVc3UdkRcDOGwc/a2tC9/UUoTZ@0BedbKiHCwiUFOr/IKZvQS90VaHQCnU1OO8DsDk6iuTa5BJXKSQa2dkRWVuSJvlkgn93NDtwxZwB7zcbOCeFZSQXGkT0T/9L8kMWB@sFSWc57ioUsIllNDqfQtOMNMIhEfgfHZGg0@Ym/SgMf7nIFe3msOf3LwaDVs51TR0uO6Z94EXO/Ub18/Biqnp@uj4jy9fOOqFAZPbdrMLE98@aZEqPiz/inuXwT2PMf1yDjcR8wKkpN8WH1frQMveDVIdFkqd0aAu4V/AgQ@d7Xf2x/g67ueLSk/LU@1fxe5lbsBdEGFta8E643hn/eXUmBWiCcSwOIklHR8goFKw6xt4kLnxNBS9R6LrTguUPrdWXIa/rRBJSZK@Crt0mVuNR58bGnuTwy4Pq683jnR0SncD2yery05WyE4fd@tGTv@/RDkea5ahjQ1rHSU/jT9Ys2SLFh2eKFeg7YX9m4EIBBRHF3Qwav0Sch9huI23JBEGG7kZIYdSHiV4mBB0yigNwPHAMv86cmZoBcqmuuuhNL7hhFT8gXYl5QBuzdCc8ajf4B7Dj6W@meNwhzUCaxTj2LnEu7S5Y7mV2jKkob244cA@K@BnDxxLGLaYBH3Wx/Sy8a/mX5m1rFCMxZcR85WHnmoTEg2kslLGr6MvMfsNxRvQBMEcPozc/an6jx/c6wB2HuwuicXV8SGTciWvinDo5jNadPtGQz5BRA0HVTEvrCqf8rkaK554@To4Dg1izgVFBuhbY@KYBl@M4ItNNsgXsiwVXfRZORfAOwClrjtW/iXNndUdDKZv4Ifq3iUqhBFYc5ESodh234Zgi7@M4FoacKTL9KXow/H8gTWbAX6cdJ0FPqGUFAfwuSjJUoRVtX5konWtz0WDdbiTUtF@9T8B8tQfmMu6Yvr25Ef8aIoEenYl58Z7DHrZzMwgAJsfBhj1/Y5O0y4C2Ti8yrq6Oe5J@szfMKb1WmKXiFtz8ypnHapdn7lbww1WunDVZDe5SVfVCNm7nPOtpyzS1lVcPo4yAc038j8IjPgCJJzxz6aVYrU5zVlHPMiMHdKgla8FpxRGTSC39euet3SNlhchMyX5982UIRaA3gM/tfnJ6kYES89x0xEVeidURR8FDPHFsk7H46JB152yI2Q0B52GLD0OQgWR8jQWiK9A5VF8CTeUesqEIGkmsDpM4gxC3rk@k5WX1OsaeTybBoTH2x30JZR/KqZYp4UuAD42h7S7vq9fBhFDufl@3hcUKjw4HHmwX0ZgcS@j6yLbSHAxGpDoG6Dfh6HUmrq/e6UOHsB9djXT8QlrPOiN9ImGUfmoGapPs3nmZkRjyjFrUGcNboeUzf3CXeiEsRCU8yU1@ReWIeQ2PbphDx87NYknl1pMv60QTDkvKRFxXK@rLFyklBNUhQ0OmYCeKNxdss8nt4N4hnn7Xg9EvWPuhAvVbYSuOTGqB5LNAGaR6n2M8NsfS9eEg4hMNGgqcgMSUKMlBWmyoSmv0U81O2q4pk0THROxS7snvbydmUmMtRQ0ljKtbJ@ZbydNggkpLOjRoHCy0tLTMqMzacH29czPG0ULT19Yqc9qPRcqaKBGVh0Z1xJPIzfjpPZ70IX/lYYTZQ29wx61VUCAMnRX3qrflHOMHm4J3nXDUss9ESZNpBUMcv/HWZ9BnXjRHhzrsXzMYR@GEdgDNQuemwDAaub8MLvuNrUE3uOgMOgHt0xAG/kYkHh4n/IgBuxgNriNOJMQfWlah1iR5lvgyEoYNv@N7ybIVmisah8OcbaYwHk2qlxImgk/OYQSY5BVl/h5Ox0iL6zxZTio5af9TtscrueU76z4uzaosN/oAoAXcxpQFhfiQjtkxyXI@Ld8qcH5fAQvHc5VXgXuHxV4K42dEIr6GSWFskLlllmB3AjuzOzE@ad14LY5BOEKgpXA7REacKMevvQCpmkmKPIelwJoqrRatqnKLcoM4hHiY3E3upaf/YOwJgT@BfunxLG6ZxQgs4tom2lIk@xUdZZRwYfPADstolsQkxToXnb7lfshJKG6moaY/T@6iBlv@kFKkw@zd4krMyBxtfJDvLtcgkdOYuFhUFtSCy3E7oIJUx7ni3Qwbfst@lic/LnHl5AyCaUtDzllI30WqJlEJyXCnzGttlCWm8rdnzNLS947aFAErs0zOrKTMuYzRXNgDpSPrK661BiMSxpkp6mlTj4VoPBgufCf17pQdMyOzzaJ103W/aQgszFahxfJRi0lbmeBxUnam8ZlimjTF2NKMeAjbV36O2XyaiDeVBuZbpTH5Bh3uolliNxUvKvF4t2TuY1H8CItes9DEU4pxR5DScvz@pEEdb9wtQTRM2V41WGI0IDIaE3m0QE2RKabS91OIuU/jPkWPFlEO7baIdvb43EnUaSM5E/LUfEoFuQQ9EbgdTpskl4ZtGF8gTJxouLGQihXOG2/CV3ml/DmCDOODAIRWHOaTcyg5wU0Ga4qPODtAO9eAtVAJkoieNmwLhzjof0wwjsqvD3e0xUNjki@dlQXSTQyJdhVc6j5Ixt@cfp40bhjKLVLQFJ9BirhHt2TT5ff36s/2hcoRBKnNn7Wlb9FDZ1y1SNjQP/anxg104KQpXTM1o9ITocGigeYC7VIuuqFsV6H9dUbC8bBu0NOINhDyOoc/i7oGwnmvFGNqo8pNa4Iiria3zDZX5TekSsJQ8hvk11NRVF3euBKAUDCm@pUSQUBYU8YelwIcesfmvBSieoyoYqWEaUkvOSpqYuc54zuIqgs8WbZKFGeVeGbDyM8EQorF7DIJIqSzzC6SQKGFbiYuVomns/uTlCCF2PC@UJyGQo9KmobxyAkBOf1z0U0kyklJeUXNwfzxybKb@hjzN399VrS@Fqe/En1iDE/ypemvq8XU11SzS0vpqqmaRA/XbjX1kUjh2gjHUuHP/ceuKXbI89gm1NpkpLQMbZ@N9Ny0y6R9m/9zpNbZKdvoGAae7Rlutl8NSbGSCsp@fwB2tcBXBojd/qd7ayxTDSY6VwDHpTPOLjnZELLGmsFSj25hp2si7cUBCsyedtBWb492dlJhX88nxtCoF46Wi8UimPjcDn5vbKtxlNQZFNKlC@2rbrcwvP7L6O15gWV/GHJKgDWzgw5pSGhSRP5gdCGZIYADFUXpvHZkxV7/qt22UzDghhKDR8MmJXU0BMULUCc2enl7xAdADFIvsD@hg@jfTyqefdeBKJoairmGotowCf6YMbdnRB68aMM@O76pYmAQzMaaidYtt7LxGSsIMpvwYHH4YvdzYp6ceRV2uwNPvUMqYkQKmPs6XWFnx65QlCK4YWTv3quI49F6KvzY6Vp@xShi8zrAmYXJ5JkwceERG/8gvKjdDHOZkw8ZWlaoy4vo5iLiU3sqc5FxdbD47wArfEhof1fpXjDMNZlO04VpqdczOHkijB6XvJl7n1QRl8/ENM2@XRpEnY2uz8EaqOsu6wImlj0PL/fkjuIxcTOnN6U2aFgUGBonxFz5vhpwNfvHicWP43b7@6QipwGQgf1dElEyofw5gch3ADwD9fQjeiKK9l/zNK13pgKKiIKDZB235Q4qNFDBcR42K79e56rVqpofLi6qanWTHvJ5Vd2sqm282NxU2/R7E79/qCwtL5dF5m67n@nlpnn5VW0SDD7hXGxejrbpJ32rwG8M1toY4vlCZd4rzzcq6xvlqHBS3YRbPz3957/8z//81/9VqOof/44fm/zj5ENcyPf9wnzz8/wPX8v4fbJ9tjB/fjI/PFu4KIPL/sZRwwf1cT5IzEf90bmTlVXAest2pGafzdFndFVlcgL2gtEvJF3WVLYZFbL6bSSZo1jGZpuh9T6EH@U5beFN0oHprTwhkSWgExzH0@g0Qxjg0XpDlCRcYAcq9eVuxRzcIxxMXCC@VcnqSDyss34M4dOSRFKALy6tWPlOPwr7OAH/yDqvdM9xAvrbGTc0/xY@vI4uNgc36tFpTj0qqkeeepTJ8J/SyjN6684XOvDOlWK0HchkPPqSXC3AzFBFHVb0eP/AuXamyO0485yyB5BMmAouLF5wXrz7Y2cZSbgWXThzSMWp5IiEL5lQJft5vv@VhuUzlfiaSbnasKLQ0LsYbsy6UYnHFypQEIkhQNJyTwiyNqAmcdPHHsl4Kpg3eqwdzibEgEHWg5c7PO/xgtai@b62eU7tpZDmiM3n5S3WxrI4QzPa@CLtJwjwhYpsJ4vsSbiQXXDEytvqJXdTvLDt/mnmE1uHSTg2tulS6TdlMYFYc9uEm@9rvxZtyC3XKyrTia9XrKYy07bfyrGq9K66485Quytw65hQn@PWvspMwogyIIEjMfvXbs8wPigwkaKmhkWSZU1Ua4Cuy0zoa9d0GmDXl5sjiwiFDzma21@m5rZbYC8Rww7CA4xUbMrXDjrdSEddGTGxL4LRObIDBm1OqDaWezM@z0P21SmMB@0YaZ8hs8l5Mp@pK9nhKLjoBZ7K7g2ORsGkTssWaT7jpu9SDxGCCUhg8ummZ3XPICw90kPCFIm7wpZDSF7Qnej0aDK2mdjnBENqpoIOu4JJkGInpmT4JTVWU3RMuPp3DIKN8i3hHd9GahHLkheWRhpSxnab4Wl2a@o4pgV77sQTJ@MIqvHMNLygK11hoe3xxS9J8i5iBOi2M9oLULsirDxD@1idLsJ@kFqchl3HOPoXykrWRcxnTkUp1kiOyZNaSjLeASvSIz@ko0DI2mTCGTlzudzcaaTTuWXtdYSDfMe2@IVAdeIEdJzAjD1D1HG/I8JyaoVKcmD4qs6W/wSh3Q0uCL/JdTABK55mc88fFNyTD6f9s0e50/6X008uY6JFslll8yqrL7ONxNJzhVbGgpf6aazSIhNq8LSfLnDaV@LDYpGAECnkTj4Uzr4UCKHTLLLSn2aFIKkhAyaF@9srAHzhFprZNBaFrDPnPnLN4Oeel1xFayv/xRjKC1f@EhZmU8nH9LTPGbUJFPvp/nolLidRYXWp@GSp9IR2QhfhTX4UXmG9zUdX5@ENqRIRtrO09Jx@SnFDihBfb6KgTC9vqJ@S1kR8TyLtpKRFqJ7m3I4TsxXV8YUnqDxRmcOlwsXFjcsEuHzEht9TxHKmLMeCEtNBi/tyWD@jQQ/tBBHk2rR3iHAkrAzERoSPUPOAbJKv3MWhrpkuC@zn5KstxG5lIDS8hay1WvQH/bxW1lx/oQwlGl4z3dXianF6jt6aoqkZOq@VqYUHqrTx/Ol//Nv@r9lxdmOp8G5Ef8fZX7Mrq1l5pAf69dj8@pjdyK6j2MrX7KRAe2B6fPof/5vqb/yF4ODLZJ3@2Vg2sFYm2Y18hat8yW6s0ENpaYna/T///M/Uh3nZsSEX63zDU4xY2VBkK@gz79J3VUcvZVu6kIgVdswCDLEwpL05/YBh1M3SapGP6bLaquJjqCNfGXsUvcSzYdaYTYXkJMPYU5BmJBUqaCAvII0JRVtZthvGbAPMm6Cpfnror0S0A/hJm3PETcamGw8jmAzNy7aIBjAnLdJ@Xh42is8zsXnHWsbYlJSNComtnZa1q4/LxA5vBuG400xbSZjp2msG1@G5Dz70w9YV7an6UXfw86jwkViyV1paLbRxuF9gO@7CkCHlhxP/EymCOhkQbQzZ6NRTIxqBQQ8hvDzOFkQK/U58J2XySZKWPQybcoaVzklMRcTHz5PrYXTHT1TpHP9LCjwyZ@pEkFautNM@1dw/WFOZxbiglOM9rwts3rBxrA6BkRdr2CHLJt/hPuB00PTHr44u2AmJayHquhTxg1arEehvOWcuY1Klec7cZdgdVjJtCe@O2Km4MdH0FzXzTij5Dk4Q8nkWdIDVC8cBbdErGX6D/XjSAsKk6LvWOFRcQta2Lqt39a0KZ125p@lrafqaRhRaQtJOzDNWNDZlFxPZUsFR5Shs4EptZsPUWmSSNo98/gMMIhmWehtuCbo77AFJVEu6o63K7GHzeC9MPHIdis@eHC1K5monmzg/eqaEeFBDd0K7vjRGAgJRcNdgoUy/D8UDomLSjHb6jsTzm/ps4ntoMNyHfYQStcPWSfBRWZb6H5H7pjNmX0pFJNBxZW0bbEdWjxh0HGIrTkGbwcFLxgVLtdd4s8UFzXCscRpoExIqk5FzqpOmitPLtnX2WkkUQS8yxdLS4yfLK09XnyHL2Zzu7WwwqORjFzC8DAgGa9Q52mTjfaWSWcjIK6Sgvt0koM8Ciws4mHVdu64J@3ztPqiUihpYMcOwrjmNhlTXx5UMMoE4Cn2sCLRHyY0yudzztRN07Oy05X6h/4m/TXxAZjgTjjYQ0lvj8CaJTOX0JOBAhQUzB8XJPUYEFVd/scuGg/YBok2EsHUVtqeGdhEBYnw5GlxdXNrc4evQVkc0YYjgHJcaO6iX4TgJMGZhBV1UHzjULe@LioF3crsHMMrFkgCdT4DTNNNxKwNtaYrZsUCLECJrwmMVV4iW6ajNzsyd/YGq7W1PI5a109AxXN@2bCXljiOZIYAMcvVa3T0i6upoF@xKqmWSl4qqzAKuiHIldocP4CvdRCJqiypGVrPeMM7dR5YS82IS2jSpSuMIvGbALBW/TUrj12p6AYIYQahPk2Ih5sX3OTbJEpzsQcY8BS9n1iwb0dedKOIAc7qxjKstSrkQZxWYc@4AiHObYkY6UlzDiPJjjRMvy2gjmaN4ReNoQJshxzvVcGZJTjPBVreRBMBG1nFDC/S/vrflqe0a/bPzbtuDorxZ/Sv6Had4vhvfksa3tKbqO2YI7GixbHMLm6lf4aJEzFLUAWMTBCF825IVMUyiBtTqO5r2MqlPUnP7LOEKsGuglXBzOqonCQK98BnInN68x6E42F2H363J4dVtSROHVNHTQo647p/YFk3mklZjSELK7wCxNA0iDtSScPtcwvBigc6ad6D3Loax6zuzeTrFsrKhIrV9p0BkT/PsnZS5jy2WNFssrWEc7@ML5tt7eeM8bA@0L1rMHN/gjQd/jDfy388c@f8WzFH7x3DHY80dj9cge4Q74rDh7NHJadgHMzjmfMJrcKPVuejgfKht/UQnip4FgAUeMIQPKX0sFdG3O8SJys3@sDi9HsFIaGkZjgF/qPNPdOefrEHm8uN2@F@18/m/c@eXdeeX17DWzBh5rdpZ4db/Pj1OVMJc@sXM4YW6K8XcP9rTFd3TlTWspjOG@f97T/P/j3r6VPf06RoiJsiFg4Svv5@bRROpHm7V64m5he/ooF055LGfzZUu9l6tSoY2D@3uVXRZgbau/jD@qxr/VUgjfkIaOtxFxLah8V5etqfiLC@aJZ9yKDhZSU@kvyYyutVfvWAl@xG9QImQ5oOtkd6okELuycfktslP9MdE@saLz/fiLLJdJ8vExbm1gZYdYclNprhovjpJ5tJKvK5scwxktXV0sLv4P4QMveAX7YVGyGNor8Nu16wk9hbsKI46pTtjdQewD/WeI8UqmpyM7Fh7e8fsMne3VOPAFlPr4uxNgly14f6P9lI96BtWVm4cGRFtfF3f7Kpgmmu2F/KG@i6FZndZ9/gPcekzzaXP1tSB3hjcRapAH/hpXkz2aUvLy/etAVLLxx9MwKJH5e@ZVf8X)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/0fdbz)

Sphinx has `#` line comments and nesting `#{ }#` block comments, block comment may be opened at EOF.

Sphinx shares code with PicoLisp, they are separated by Sphinx raw string:

```
r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)
```

`;` is for Pyth, `}` is for Bracmat.

Answer (score 1):

## 357. [RunR (JS)](https://github.com/stasoid/RunR), 15960 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfbIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbt c u c 11    .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']put 294 bye!\`_ #s['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{










































































































































































































































































#-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>

<attache>Print[194]Exit[]</attache>
 
#^^aa>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()~#class C{function:Main(a:String[])~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#aa->=323
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8[;s]p>0::&&1Pr"93"sgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrl61op>a>std[]!!92[ ]?42e>8053在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#";f?n=  unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@NIdiD440TD@0ekQHWRFAmAAL9JkSqVStWl7qpWTUnV3W6SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElqWJm9m7OY3v3vLPjjfHY6x7PnvfG541Y38bteXxr70bY9@OGY3/yH1D@uLhwXHj@g7n3XgIgKJFS1XgdsXFxkAjk58uXLzNfvpeZeOjo3vBnP4vhxZ441nxgORM2MbwJ67nmqeHK7N6c3dVNL69lBQFT7bqD6ciwJ15FiDGVMUu3B1N9YLC@aU0MN808w2Adw3LOIF5jbHtqTz2jVwdfljHbOGMHdtfsAQQ2cU4M23xtuBCXY@y@YV2MLias64xGut3z2Ng17QnF5hl7ooOnP@2eML3jTVy9OzEdG6IKjD2zLX3U6emMko9dg2cqMgDVPaE8yzElxh47rmdACU7X8DwHA8sQqLum82j304@upFcz7CMdkBpbxuxK8arKPjcNt3c1h8Y@O37w4Gpoln0iOTZ7cB0lNcd2pxPnYHIVfp7tDgxbZ5pclrWrkQUg5sSwSplS5mpUEdrTmJjdpXIg4oHpQuvqfiuyrm5Da2FbbjFjNJ7MmcTbX7essG09pnts6k11i9LZ01HHcIOE3kR3J6Y9YGfmZMgmQ9ML81Fqb6x3DalnWObInBg9ZpmQyen7UAC03WMnxvzMcaHJfZiObc0ho9E1@yZmCfAAgHglJkODwxnpc2hkewKdg@nMAzQsI4CWFGKQ/r7RmQ6YM52MpxMGuPVMT@9YALQzZz2jr0@tSZp1IA6ITOFnQ8P2OzOAkwHEscOxejkl1IxFn9d7PZaBfgx4nBjMBKoRWhWWzUI4c1ygGqQKMPKBUb/mdTRm0GbQRH2nwvKZDMTvhyGIrW55jo/MMmoYacNYpTZDuE9cZ@DqI6BGzyCafnbwhHldxwUf/DAtH083genqE7a9zeL7n96Ps3rYLLLbEcImqrFzaIJYEMlOdWsKPSTaEg60jxvmFrDJ4hvxCosDWbQMy@VYDoZtiWl5IJKaKYMDxr@WVeFXYFqJ5VQYQfl4Gsvpu/rAtAwOZYBQitjxtTzT4J7Jsaxa4ikHjtXnybpUWJFlS6xQZMU8K8K9zMoalIagc0wt5@FXgB9AKwMqKvyyOQ5o0e@hn2Jf22N9fWRacx86ge@yvMqKABHwVQGyVgII8Mxm8ZeFH6G1fEVhT4ZA7aF@CuAlyzxBbmSEDAmbUIGHsrWlEEdElsuL94ZYPJAOiJYvsSIUXwBK5AAFoKxWguLzGV4Rb2hYlp9t6GE2wraYgR9gXgQ6lID6GaBlBolZhB/4gd9pwNg04GIaMCYNmImmgTuLRUC6AsQVoCkLPr2GuncCBfFytB4RHzg6gFGR2sjEVCQSQIDWYlloswLLQUfIYkfIZxngD7gUCwz4WEllpRwrFRnQs5xh0DYq4IW9RAX@qQI@KgKD9lehA6iAkwrUVgGoms0zIUJsNYvxkDcLeYE0ag7y5MANDacW8Af5oGeoUKQKZWpaedEJATctD/XNZ6l3agVo3SLEAd00wFWD7qQBtloJ4jFvCWhYws5bjKc5IXSkA7QKdnfoh0CMPOBDcCEtuLViltNPt8ZDvYPcmufs9DFrAYdBAckIWTNYPXjmkJqASgbA4CgA9DXoAVkgRxaaNpvD4i8FGMB8uo6yP@ASn@PQR2aGDBuYlUOseNEnE3bAbpLAHZc5J7AyC/omTBddHdkaDnKDmFQAx5zIDAqBudVwTlEWIE6zVIxH3Kjj4tQPU0fPcF2GaUFe8NLEt7xpxzNeTXFyWuDVB0ZoAL/s66YVIkCDU58QV4Vn3IPy5sto911nRCN4hHzJcpzxmjkAuOAZAnronBkL1BdMUh@PLZiKINzgMyEgc6aTEEMST7RUjhBkwnzdoQkAqShg4aZrdIn2ftUhdxaY/TKKFabV72QRyr3IHJVlYwf4t4d57KllVWDyMLosW1d6xqmCIXweW56/EIdgZoP5yQfR0UEAQcwJixDSHU2mOfM4aFnPGS1XjTOtg7DqQxNnG@tMn0Pr9YFfGTN9BGISQ1nEhhlyBD2GtyC2BAiCWK0D1nPs@CSEcuaCZACVDmtC0gfSZGKODBApHciCLZ4jpJFlEmadOXRlolZOJhmSY3KFULJwlVA8IBcJ4IMF5tDetItUw7JNm3oQzD0eCk6uofd4mDBxWbOpw8@FSXLsi80yOjDhEaIWkbpghjWA@r440yWIOPEbtgeymiczE4Va6PkDpw@d7cyEuoO4BFkXsLtEBCRBGDSTu7JAJMcONDqxmMm64zGDcBBCoHs@yJRgXndemuw1RFpDkMu6U9eds9kYWsIcQapJ1@n3ofe@NsZDAMFGPdadd2F4QiNj7xF6DnGk7ni5mgvfpgFpbJT09p78IhsYQHaQAvoo8mOXX1RgPKYqECl0m0sItg6Uwip0x3MiC4AJc/QdR8bwnmN41Fkc9yQc@liYZwxoaMA46y@Y0QglHuilNklqPeA8/vBC@FigsLIyWJTfCz4ybBg6XeiVMOih@bBNd1kfNJeIXIDCm97tGuOJ308cYmemHRGiDh@gEEWhkg9M9obC5l22faXXQNKw50QEBBQqEfWxL9vpyGt99QhEBttYyPGcs1jza8VDitMrpYsvMM0SBi/ENTiMaUigRElMYjpBVoLc0ewOkRdOkNuQEAOjzZ1erz6ERYt3R0zqh2UjNiqwHUFWwiDEYz0MCX7WdUDy2EJY9aUATLoUcAto3RutgOyESFq9aKis6DIwxduAjhzbWQEViBnCxSTLMdQW1BmPkGvoVtgZabh4S22EDHuhseNEBnPoeOy4MDI405mTekZNFuldvlaTCOeKJGj7y1MrTBlxnPAnOAtChrEFuhwNMRypIK7qwCmAiXGtA3iew0uMIEyjnmD5@J0R6@edCeZS2zZQ4tXdOQcC1YPpGQqaM9N1gQ2e4iTB56BgMpGpn8KcAPoXclYkB437q4XL2KP3ph1zdlW16WKg/NITTnWX9VGrcUHogEGUiPe9eLJK4ZQzEiUqzniiUFZ@FyEhJZKhyRN9UJRgkngAjOZobncT4tIQE9NMnE76JTEJDszIZTT2sT6eXMXuJYRhpxmdwLgmX5UNYPqWJLhLGEaYYIQiY4TugpwBgxBE93K519HZBXAPUNFne5QbhUx6qnIuLMuwe2FZPiEQl2h9ZV6E53bJIUVmNawBJqea0ySxRMB3pARlFCFAUfy5FQNI2uNxJNfwwKlNixsswUWRJDsPhX2YABKEjAnCh9k1J21fXLlzJxBcNmo16GwgTQHb7CWjakKwCiQDp4bEMkkjfiHyxDma4NhIJKG@mPiSYwNiE/TUWp2dT4YujDjyXwqQCMgq2NiTA8L67fypeTLtXW1oGwMxkYijDoQmszsRqwJM/nw01G6ianyJqqBKxJGq2HkxP4G@1nkpFBtU9JO5hofib81HJdLCCcTA76srScSz@mGLDr0371q@SMBdMNg5N@oA@if@6kDIiNK@TBAM2msjlQPB4cDhsCe7xw9r/ljkkUrHtCtLAZbT1S0K3sTkYpD30cG9p7tPf7G9AoZldipXAxQzVyrgVDudSQN7quRkrbIZhbEAfL99M2zMuJxGFPxoJjmziKg078LkMgvIefj0k6skAUkIyUElgBt/V0QangaELqGje8MrkzAbpFJQZJglSMukAxbADB2IOsbrAT5Ppq9fY@NdRWrshyNm1lTnAIJA5cAO8skYeUUAC6I6fT4jUl6QQk0bV28XrmjKAJ@PUGq@igyJ0pEu89Hhg/2nNQLrL1ZIlETxJiBL6W5Phj5vTXuGsCoNsD9wdVlKXiCO8jThupLA3e4SgRdty9bABwCo68gOk6xRUDVvCLjvXa0bhUrdsAeQnyBclSuj8lD3fRGN4IFTXBdV3lWzKEUsJqswaOWMFcYuT1vdfN4o5srRaau7KLMXBUorrTAPBHKjC1EnnoQh8kKK9MVqH/2jR9cQ90iIBFVACjDzLCZTWZ4loPYimSzuKXugoTmWIX9OHE9kYlJR4sFiq9z1SPmMpN@fmZNEJsmfahLSQum7uwfa/SCxvw5IKxmkNKAujjOT28dNk64HfcR2LGfgsC3Iw6XDoEAQm9ZWc3fg2NdaSMdArGoM912A/@LCjT6GucZ8TYoj5Yqqq3wHR7e9M@DSaiGLRCIKESiF0ssv9VMdyLWo99HBl/swiaj5TCZ0Z@gCEkTyELnQ1Y2EUgCToCDZx2dlBcM9mGujPYiQIpsgWGmf0YUZdxfRKwOJY8rKyvQrUfrYuUbxl878SteCEN61wBEh2cGnTx4dfLr/ePeL5kTL55f8uUy5AISD8jogC8lDTjccrVt8aGK1EFwMxoaLwwu4wBQUlGAJfuq5wLhlTCJzBNb0Gr57lfjYGdpxL3m1MmcYK720u7wLPcbBx5P6GUHR7lmojLh8CxDnc@w/w8lk7FUUBUb5cNqRQWlVXnYdSx8olA8mBstSVFRdDg5xXcNblQOQ8eYGz8EXt0B0mNMKom6NHFBeaCMRWQNLcPC0amWZgyHowrjbaLhJOezBVBulBxoC6MpKWDdiwOQD2vrPoJ1E3rU/ULUS79dqRsspYpBsafhD2o2@AapTAmYrIEXyipc17zTvsDlwaYR0FUiMyVu0yOExnAssBoIkrZqinh8Qh7gFrpciryAavZriai5wKSWfyRXVQl4BtQzUNJBZJVxzk0b6pDuUJo4E8CSnT@sGkV7Y97q63Ze3fEeALMh9H0JVs43nzabdAgG9eYdww828xrzVUFvJKrueZctPn6xC712qHvbdIAD6Ljmha9KTreFnPf06O@vpNLp6TJmMxv6cI43Z410QpF47wK97RnTsYQYlGqlsLaVVMPEbZcWCkIVZBbwhpRQYUDDTQtdTEC8JhF4UD6HnAN@KZGCL1QxeD75pHuEjqHRjvzeduEcr/yjX4GqpNwYi0mJzF7m0h@uDE5gdw56PXBoaF5k0OzPiuI6ue3y1EjL5G6dBftDVQgi0Kh@uSNvhVjF0AspF6jlwDuhXuGw6XKwyotIPPQ0KJJxw8QEkCJt2DwbAZyAzr8gurwgviUKWq3RiO2c2QusYrCR1zAlf7HemLm4gmr1o3SB5VuNpABpVLsLXaaexY3T5KivPTLUAJVBnI2Pk4FICSFfECgyqgs53KVEX9HDFGoZVRsJtGIAvsbt7wMW6Bl8vkkaoREGX2mfxiavsSl8quvQaevMNshVWPtLEfqMfBwRY3jOmVRJ/BZSkE2dEiT6n9RaMvBeIu8J4PhlCjaGHiXrNGRv2VZ2Pa4SJZJX2duNxYPimnTiPb2xsxCvxejwNrh1wbaNrB10pcO2QSyIXppPRRTnS5MLYBuXAsFb8shFAniVb2AdmKDm8NscJvVGpZFtpvaH6Tw2fSWgKoDyklvABcOLJWg2dyaRYP8M9G5DfI3Xfw75z1HXNsU@Cj0Eg4H6fBlkiAqj3KM27RhV105spMqq5oDQaKGIm3HizkWm2mufNXqp5GU9j7mRVr4F@CMxrkhjJA9eZjkFwa@QqEvC2ZCNbaVU7tXgmvpVIlCQLCtKTyQ9LyZTOaZ2IG9CnEs1mHEjqU6fRHboEb5bWksmQUIBH3wQtw7IScfm8BOV3kq1kKg55k/E0sOVaPA506SIRPKo0rgjwTvTAnAEpYWDCFBfdUyAGSZtTOFy/NMbDuRtNEK66gZSNK@iLAwB4TgK5eJRLvub5owLdkqYfyL08HQi3uHiH8tJ4zrm7wDFtKkvHTYJ591Tqj5yJrnwmg9IkR6bL@EZckSSYCSmGQ6JqPzY9HMK6bThTL7rSuHIBFEuH0OPhFJhlcOYnDb3KHAtGd@iw@OZdgM7C/R6cSnDrSuIbYAGAXleGHzJRlEpwswSkCzqlYQJfpPMttCqjEhKc9QRr8/nC@JUcllalPCyDBZkD23ENCUgCOQQ6kkIHnYQ680/FHNDK17V9CT@WpjRUvE0DOOIDy9GJtpxdR/aDxqNIftDPIctToydYwD/6wB5l3hau0VO2BNqlddwhzBBQG@TEWthaIz9CcbxxT57MIKuQwAk3Gsm1OxA6z1hP07RCN9@vBHHYK4DYQ2gk1EptUHGDKEmFyKTfyPt8WSjQ0T89vL/P105ossXpFdfR2iOnNwW50tebnhr2IM32oT@ZtjMygQxB/tcn1lPHmXAtHzzrVma40myOppZOaz5Xl2VuzNd1Oo5FS0E3ZV2kn7qebul8ESqI3f3sMcj6z46PanIlkkjRT0c3lo3rkKuL5fQ8iO450n5rsD3k8Y4pbuZFnLeCo3TIZvyIAkZM/YN00EZBeBHDgyGFeyh@eAnDR3iIDmRlfxWBvGGgn7BMCfFgHZ4i8gPP1cwlhq/VwcJ0KqXjguMC23NVo/DTSb@/FJyl4BMJWZO1CM5RMD9gt6QjRlHK80R42m4pTRRQgdKEh@7WpitSujGdwJPDncXH4SGEoWEFW4tPQWLB7TOY9C2Uq0BpQRGdH4wzQMIe4y4JsW7ce2NdEEK9a@sZMNjGEk8txDZoAMHkpqBII2wqzF/7rtIQsh1/z9LjbNUBnZ@WVbbrfJcbdSqXq3MKX5XfbAOI7Xo1OMW0LhmWFI@HyQgq4QY5qJq0sX@tquExDY8W2wXKUhU8BdSJmZaRmrPifusirnhEhj4Tm83ZhxntC9BL8Aja5h1lYFSxwHX0qgYxcV@G7cyZBBIfpuIL190h8BmWmi2TEtpnavcdqyfxXTLoMIzrV9hA/iGF8GicfwLSMN3gVBwdS@RZkb9GDtRdg3ulSevXE0SO4IWAYPics4uT9OkFa8CUdyp7Y8uctNilPHHaQyTJZOraVw/rcRnUdfW5J/hnXGps9@lHnzUyLQ5BGOm481XirTgLznyC4AyCEh7OBRee1JmYE5IE6CSCifVVZUBqRpskgD7A4AVUWViQXyNE/cK4WNSlb4CmmjAQc28@SjMjeSn3LX0yMWze5/j243py830iv5gaFb/jbzpUWIZ2ZkAyNTEOUKyyo@P7@0@fytBzvUR8H3dwKjAc9e4QBJR1lQ4oGa18hX3Yi7MPMU8S1XYBhhpoH20/P3TqKnR60D@gdOQdA8NNQGASN1@6EEz7XZSRS2g@gfC8VXdCNAqBJYwk1ImAVVbi/8zmqpaPZwV6fIooCeRO3KkAbc2kPLXNV7IHEw3JrZAkzpVVmC9qmwniYptqknqPa45w6xg0LBIaoQaNBpNeA5eDxCJrtar8DACkRQXMHSB1RZGago4G19Sg6WsQDCINQfCz196w542MVG6lNleBosNl/qleXv8IXISwDNozVha7maDxfm0gcxz4XiDn3M9Inb5ypL3CNrlD5GvOlDw4MEVMh85XLZ@TWj6FBYMMWQktxWBFApYQ889c@32W4onzg86D2SggkWTnIdE1JDm7uCAask2NEQ3BpTLeGJeB9gmM6ZEDtXnkn7eOSgc0Wv2DJDhmm4IYqFnLO7UYw0V45fSKdCqditF8XDo07ROH9ntCVzsjq3mUCMPcoxPres6@6Q3ptpQ0xIGn1dZh5406fbqtSEDbHv6GOgXQgrovC4MQqStP6UFr6ytKXj5EslRsx@hP7QHtPqKbSa9uSSmVS5S43@mY65ICEfBcWPBckQyYFPZnTc7JanCAG5diYD4CxsW1l0XVr54/Ykt0h9lhArn853/@Rg/of711hjBR4Mpj6GjD1I0tJfXXNpafFT10W92wfIF8apk6EYZct4Hs6i5USbdCx2rQtAkvSTD9j3BLwW9x6Jt4A6nxhm7GMec7gsFzdSGrNtVsYJnddWmvnMfiRdH2Dyh2PSICF4JMgzIR6@KNYMz4FkxExUY2djtSwaEpRp2Zt/twOpnyOwiutzaiOcbfTWPTT5nJ6x3VANVR75jGDU3u6ifTniONTwahnFpYkXZRe9oDlkAc8LeD2@hcXX1eQdccwDwbPNclW0xtyhk9busVnj31xlKHtPAe99FAGN1Qgmvx@7okpv9GVOhYTzXTots79kQfOnQU/zSEgmdNpQjRzCtktvTOHGWQ4fv3svBkAXCcWjeVymTXbC2Px@vzoyZJ@cvl1blncpfTY9UagcLPs0p8FY0q7J9wvaVVYboyR7olab2Icy0zX3Uw4VrScE@T8hinuKNzurLlFtTHCak7tXR34bqhiy/wCLYR1q1I@9PGE7PrgDgwZmpRVrVg6ohMGMQyg6Nxi4LwODHdIscfzFVk7IFaiJO4FLpWswCnO8Ejo2v61DswNH5UEw/ERjqJ7KyjVNc5w99a8WEIqim/r57RXq/E6h2Yk2R1LR3m8bXTwdLiIC4@3tJRz0zPoNtqwp6sRHTStVaGLw@BYNkvuox3W7f2TMvx2BHdbyLQwAUq8PvqDh2lpanbEi2GR9038KDgjMOiQXVr4FiF0kDR4ba21aduH/m@/3xXDhdyKFW9hUMF4o9jq/5zLV8/UdyT2xqI3gJz8XxrxHnDFLuKTfl7L@trB4oBbtytrtmDTIlyygpf6ltTMG65nOnz4PlzTB3rSBtMHeM5idMg3WGGcgkcE5eL2D9PabmbS@u9G1O6BrZ4WyUijXtiGTBZ0f1akzIto75nDjWTeXcW1bemxtRYqWgcdl4a@K7yDUrGuyOV8aux6a/U4@YAvpoSpnrta4bvhDXO0@i7kZnoltk1bhdllpnaGKTvMarOT8DxBB3Xcwzs6XipVZe0M/vpzSQbjoMh7fSWsMOY9@VDpVskpSX53DPod6PGxDU8PCBWy2UyGV@Aiey4LHlu0qSyYd6XJr8vFUwhi5IXaXGXzY04V5dBZIkeQVzLgrR1ij0lLpcV27SNyRzv78hNO45jvU9LAVPtmSiKgWRJR21varFr4o7/EglbLF14uODR6a9btOCzja9bAn1Qab6p0aNbQu/UmhJueo5wQ2rZe/PyTWSD6bZS8GVuXBPih2@t9bKkvxqiyiW5eOOo4xKq0zEsnT9mhdxN8Mpy9kZ4y0zD36zFzV2@pbvYio9dYUrjORDL7IGWMjRGBnlvkPL1Htod8B9rE80c/K2LnhlGV5ntG911CcYm8AUb70t7yBFhaeLYoF9N8Jwf6ikWniT1Q9dx4GDXbyWRD0b6wOCGMG7ilIsFCzxNw9W6hXP10kWFn6DpQraFhYP1XQIG1Ykx94LnSoCP511o1@no9uW2K4O/i2ug7zDa1x1hvT7F2kNnaA@NIT83HvrWDQ7ojxNuuOQm1AHrwRCPso3HS0fco/S0HMt6F3oia@SM0nH6K3Hax5df8c2t94I71zsQ4T9uXbzTJ5x3oGPtqBkaU5iXPGfijA2JfOuSWrjQw@/reGiwSf3zriDdqOcDRYLnzwv/Vt1yoDuT8Zge7bE19ehGWSV6Z/k2uanPj6bQoUjHHcivnVFH9gNl/9wKbYGvZjEdc9Id4kvjvGcbA6fTHZq3Id0x9IltnijBkg/3vpPuipQxmXQfg2XLBPK6cxn7Sy0af4SPg3WN7q8e8WktdNwgr6xaoaPXsqWxftL1@GooulgFF4Qjo5G/vF2h198rr6bmZAE0cpYpXN7l2xLoWIe7f3pirWRF70gs2LB/qmJtLyUhHQVyyciAwKOuK3b5nFtkiGWz/LYOoWgtCaPIuZT3Ibd/9odWB83Iui2EL/WvpUNLKyc5ezgdeNcZJl@u74GIhrf1yxZ0ljmyZA1zlm77j3Vk1iwFX3KEZxtkrqlx455K/sZNFUqnWpLumPBowwOabrp2Dc0yxx6/M6m/divOP8sEuvjV/UJOm/lqZdpvmJ7R51sg6LpNRBw5Lp5EBhlE6uJOOq6gIzPnghdnXLYzAKYuWWyROEi7TmxZeUxodfOHc6b0xafGQMez1o/MCR7WXNErqMuuOl50K@yvT3XP/PoUaraus6HFBr4N6UZf7UffCniP9YHZfbjUECGSPoH9k578sdT9Meh6W5wNTQ9PNIWOGxamsMvxToy9rg16w4qUV9ftQ2MViwHEX4NcmXrV2roznuPbYnNy3bSsbk5oldV/rlMd1x0CuxGJs@loPPX8x2oc6MxUdBV6dELh3pkJwKVXwFrZULcmq1eqI0uuIIX5k@LCuU4a/9K0nAH7spRhILSBEIbC@YqOcw@m5yd4IMe1V/REKvsdtz1xoUNyecVeQdsaWSaZtjm5eTVnMsHDOcETK8NnDnxDQXmEd/nu@0KQjldT5NHtsv7i1eRb5nfoeUfO1O0a6AztjUTVAr9UYy84fYxvdDhoL@UsqqV1HQuGFzislUOm69jTieRO7RtnhcKNs0KFzUqFSDdgia/vP36WjPYGOq19mxRqgPI39az5wrX2wMCVTmbaIIit56PLqQNd4j63k/SUjgrfkmcXjTl1iV3fd1bpO0/mMIG8s8IEzH86um90cdvw1rI/dR47tgOz0RgY5eipwd/5XzrosTojZnuEb7UDfXq3FnNEYNdMQlza0MdGB9rXWrjeZS7igO/rE33NVERrg6T/ha5b@4ppdQz3JS36RdzrVNplhB4aM9It1ncYPgalSbfLRWJcj1saI0s7Nt7YcWx@J26bgYf6@GauAlMB3d59o1zGg/hL6wIr9bPlqh6e8lMiRo8bpVhXV9foOBa/33AmyTb5mQDdNQ1PeYQ2DiiskGMSSF/ejTykeCMPWahGIMme6h5t0q9WNRYg1dl7HAEa6m7XwZ0w33HD6ZyIYYJb2HR4tp8fHOgA4WfAsfTu1LfAeBta1qgzottahSHSmk@NDr4V1CFrHhN9dr0x@cqQb8ogcqIrNAAQsCsc1AWWeALaSPL2aWtJj1qmqjmmG3HqtdvldFhHsk2j@1rHVTOH6LVYm16Khzorn5JzzVp1ZBjRKrKi05vuK0fS8tE1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclNy9uBmZUV@yHTkYGbzMu7MGtFV8cbUmWd1fvpIXN1Dcm39Qe8JLT7x@VDaXet5Ing4f/w3scKTMLtQi4wPQKs6/YdfEB@6tr@41164BPHm/TN2SHgjW8BrGMnWK08ZIEHHxno2lpXCWg9e2rx1YdB5NzVqEfqmESmbSXJInY9MSTDPpXIENzseo0c/tKXsosmUSdGT/LtIOBOg/QoeP8rTOY/V2ygRnkjHvZUFU7YWSHnH/9cRdyzgDOAvOVMpLFHT2XsPTl4dHgsjz115fy0O8S3I67JcUuGFbRSJrIk9VJ3I/ud/Dhaz/Qmyr0jVdp7dCBjgjX05jsaEjxwZ27psXbd07c3qiv6Wi0IY43JagHx4fHjR6nFK5ossTd0nZGRjEbvHR2l8U2Tj49WRkdzP4DR0Xdma7Mf7KtqckX3fWbT7uA67rmipHWQjg3QRqEzPuR2WW4VrrrO2Ogdz8fGZzB5Igf33rH4wtpKfqqfmgMchay8llA0UFlZLuSSkZPZoGwbbvhc154n5hi5ZZceCn@sPY6CkkNWcbOrpYebdvyvSjEs459EeL9MauZ6b52YEoyMwRBdiu79fRFTVXUdnY/0PrQry69trOUEq/aHLef0HbaSDV95kcIgaQK9SjJvPUdelEbAuhW84fK8HwjOztpjMDcBCIMLKwf8mWHPdVuivaybxIsK5MZDbTcm@dJ4hw2p8ITPKVqAXrnHFx6pZ4kuOZO3FHzsRrLs7d07uC3DU5@WN6f66NNn7InuoRGSmxNGMTbeAeOFZPRSwnUrtIC3dju15wIo7UZ4g/Hq8VxhR7rbc@z57PZNOHoHFad2Mi4cwkIfJTIsc2aumqu6fF3ryepjRreVzV/icOZLcnDUOI0P6O23/5mqZjJkegifaoZ7b2mZYICzBLr0Odqzi0YdH4SsoYtyiwwByZXa6CNjhsdR@GrwKqV@5fxWuGHuKybXTyc3xZVuiMvdUN61OAxkWTmj3gAwf0Mcy8th9CPHOhs68p7uGt6K88crEbqpIuUbKlKOcOfXpQwugtLGou9eL@Ljqwv@Y2VvPTYmbm48dDpmbmUddvtoZJI9RmPp1@P94xS6S8dbBo7/ygf3ry7vbGqsLOix/np1BHGak5VRwASN4ZReibgevbxB2gGZ17AHJrevyO45k33y3aCYhW88rz6LYI7vT8frMQbeiHb@r7LzpYSfg87snHnsHr4atxDTV@j@eD5udfg6mZaFC4NoZvTh8W7Quw6PFC1S4gKLL54sBePLo5PDo0iYa8xm65ReabZOh1wZsyj10@PcUrHb9eenK4i1/n0jEDeAH4fPtXIQZ3YfH11nCai@DScjK4j5WLcXK6ZLDdZzJvSm4crIJ/MZHaNc2dJDfoptVZzbXRG8pNjDhGyaULantNtoWb/dXtcrj40vaO8BxCA24WIJB@obXjJmuWGAIWVZO1Cdk4Xws4Tu0Xho2rOVUaN1eegUaeKlt2IY8Dc8IUHUOriX9u278Dei@XuonhyYcE8k7FQqmVz@CEn0pVq0oZvYRBuSm/QCLaS9uGAb/kurECEGr8H6r@miqTlQog18z1YgEJPaJhRTq6n5MtvBr35UQEROUokYRAa9grIabPPcfwO1UlEv2UaNiRWR@e8Ah/Z5uY1ZgIvWMaFOTDpR2eYEYjaD91cZfS6BXTBSu0HOV/MZ8MlK9E3@qv@GL6C0ef7k4Mn@0fHu8bOjRqZ16b8BHFTCtqG0wM7Ah9meCHX3yQbTObc4TW@eW1AcfcoB1XUvqBeDml2pWm2paotKiTuYZ/PcthWFXoJWpEvATxJ5aRSLnRKCOOygxtQ@/vvvFf4@Mr1WDU3EQYtUJrRZhWVWFTzWYWratP34q5@ooVj8hFEFP2KEBftGgqEjDhyn55foGez2Kyjxwe7Bo2dP91mA4KLTnJm9ybBWznMb0twwA7RT36RTYTUW97PEoa1qtfiDOBAmLsdZhV5bJ/vN0M8hWUAdfOHdz73FEpsEHygYDxtF@c/fUC7jMh5wTkLaeIBUHIqFLk8dZWNjgx1DJ2H3nx58tv@UIf779ykYSYQg2DG@M/tnP@7xLyAENm2Czze5I5pHyCaIEH1vPniZfPG@O9Kchu54/Uec6IsD9FZ5@KmD8FstgkBfwoB@e0bm6K6YKkuS9SD@0SnfklxQEHWhwGo6rqWjVTjXY6emZ@I77YhDH420LXd2PH5DhglltotfqMLvYOn0OQ5AfWpPuCEk3xxKDHqaHLKcNNskZPnHO8RIwvj2BnT2jgEiBvNsEyasSYW9hJ6I69UVbvNAkurxa1kC0BVySTgtRRJes@rmKU1Xeftr/0QZVBm4J@D@ju@eZe6B71d8Xx/cv8rdzxXsaNetwC1wiSKElhv9GnBEQvoj7SMf5rK5nYkF4dBYXcBXmTmCZjolqmNyXgK/S8COF3ASjc@g0aC7QYv59iV4eYbbSqDpyIqiYJdCsVem0/3GjB@1u2JCspAv5FQFkJROA4Bk832A7xBzgMlkBYaJcGqOay9AlNre3mYi6r5GrVDlLats2s@z4osQ0U1IK5wNEbkGgzyQZZED4up@Nph8UmoSsyL3iqtxZFw9B2YlisfZC/22TwiRJYBYnEYGGhGf4TfcJu48MIXawa@eRb4HsukDklSYk8iVFAXfMsOnzgS6DwzSxRd/uGUGPGrKZ0C0MejxLxuSBVLsj/L1kbV4oTj48Ig/1mTkARxUNnN1Mo22rfg5gjhCEBVxVfdtPGfNSdNuKbxvMuimP1zRmW1w/7IyWNNneb13r9ufTFy1HonEYnePbAeV/AdQGZbQFC2rqIXkokq53Moq@TXyi4HqoJGbCygO2BSwjK5hvnTG3u7e/sHHh0@OrtlYpJTxq8mA79e3U01JTjdaoSMerdZyk9x7oBw9vvcgaIgF0oUINwbG79dEvakmi7U7BLl4F@Rq1VZheLV26zH@nL8tfhXfrHYTapTpGh5q5j3KpfPY0gN6q@pq4VppFbXy@ZtQWsBTIqD3@Cux11BNJM8vG63tetOOxa/3hBUD4XlM3sJBAK6mt7WpYGe/XjmsWPjN0WP88JgXHYvZ1WNR3MyiCS98I3/inCyMnPkBkYhIfYNigEUKshIkXTv6DrmMvjDFp/FvonLbX1HLRhGEC5mbKB4BdRx8XhW5yMKQqG9DcwjKoWV2hMCiFLelGZj8C81ocmtQiaTgf46CF5zwP7g6q8xkOnyVSCK3I1hpdpNZzgBeUoABjdLdkynoP0@cMTdPTpvs943A9dQB9nt/ypVyg308HUG6Pj2eGrThAZxbgsxAyXiIKpelgEv4VjlnKbR7CuU10DanX3F51MsnZkl5aMx65gB4eyKZBo72oaq2WGi5EytNljrtuEhttmiFG4fiR/iic5Ts72W@dbZAQG/oMij9xiwRP4snKy0oH8PjZ5@fxpPiqr5EZmR9u6q9q/ZkQ/SL6s2cRJ/4ozMw1rqKW5TL17kEhF0FzO2aBd9GKpfloSfQt@5qKLkfTdxH4AQxItEf6WOWmNrcJpzMyJtoJuw0GcuS6tzepM1SKVKo4EERMqOcfXLx@Tuh23OWUGrQCTDUs3v4eG2OWUOV5Ra4qZAk28Rvlu2BxIVWEpMC6MCQpUJga9iFQM0AjPggkXkHhzwYD2nhQZb1VkTTJ5xoXdhBmlCtWf0Oi3yDbllyFMvlit@gy1yxzKD3XWeHsgJgr/G5QK4H6vrmYoBmoP7KQmzByK9zvBiVG@OIPPTtzAA6sYiN2MD8DANYCwuu3aGLv8S@DWMF5INK5dnxg3YpqYgstFczcM0e7ltwM@ehiud/mAaGqbKUNF7lGt1HmA0tA7a5QRw0UPeABox4haXGomS4@hnpRd9U1Rt7vZ/RbwVImcMJwH@vrx2AQ2uOwULTirjVzP5nP8MPVYuJTVU9abunqXg@U4WbWs2zPPtwsylJm41M7e6mDlrU5NWsCTq5spW7f2oM@52DgdIURZZlOUXZOj@PP9h6Yj7XCq9ml1m19OpkrBYa8qtZSyzV0ict9uTJF2/ab5Li7HT@SmwmNPpg8t7hhajmUNGPVcrsfKeQjZ2U8bujTNfzJ2wGeis7Ya/hOukz/Cf3617EraO7039N32uKiyzWbOJXpsWiqCiNeAv@Sd1/ARdX/Bt1uS7vtN68STZ0fTKbM9M0x16vBz9nCBKkljxiUO4d4PSUXmFNepICRddo1l@sI@h5uNU1fMlTvtvGEDIyOds1BoPpvj43pw8mj7/8PLie4fX66YoFiVYqlZCkxtXgSlvPx5iW0f7sJxuX6fMn7e0/@@ZIMTbwcYiP71w@RveRmv9wY@PDe/dyubSmadz95Msnv7i7u5u7n84/aeR3clJmY/tP/2RjQ9O2NWWj5XlqK944OflC1DI5Uf6zH8XbT5583fPq2f/zG2/qKt6KcDtlReATcGWZCk68l@Cnooz1rlfsdQx6uRqb0187FoSfbzC1vlP8L987fBWbxOqa8rkLz0nsVaxQinEnOMCXDXynsXpsG5MVLmNzpVargbP4X/4t5K9/DHAwZr4Nt3o@gFWYx@pSjbJcxOoFcKiaBuX@39/4RgRDziZqJMYF113WgEvMFTVxpwXXFl3bAtoBlDKKEqSzJ8OJ4TC1dEe9gx4TPPCwDTSobkyaMfyKLzu8y9jTRiqVasltCS75Oa4RKaqqNVX1DnAD6cOtWk3aYtzQYTabv4PGmpO0ojVwYMI07rDP/yGu2KrA6s8N7qkQK2zcfXG/XodKZevZrXqKLn8k0aAqlkTHuSuyNHsRBxWk0XrxiI8cVhczJU1Mp9N8OM2QVNJs0ZPw4vdYLAzBIcuuhi1lgSR@aOz908X28frz/@3Pv//n36O/79PvP6ChRLtn9pUtSHQKQ6IO191KpVuvi3VXPG@ivw79KFMpVUpK@7KZ2AIO1HrK1MxHF/F8Nn7EkP3DBMCaScoNFxVb94tHfz22CK7zkHo0zI/giSmA@bUgxxLVyB1S7Vo6mFr9I6VS47TeklAgqkkNtZBvSTxXgGW9zBp3oZlErVgWW3Utrx1C06kib7jhpsecGGiGhYCOPr71Rd3qYczCV48GxepBtvoizfumC9CtC7FGQ2kZNCEEYezuRmWjVClUNKUdBl6/WPV6kGEYT7zYaSy8OHViC4LGwq55NSxoitDDgh7M3icdSEYRDjYLr4jz6tWe3XjR@j5cG/BH/3CFXrxvUIgfTEmuXxusom5pWSX/YWFfY@93CTBPsG6n03nd7aAYoHf0rq5O9Kk@0@f6pDPtzDogQ7Ep/HDUMCZLsWxe3YzdYWurJMTeNDbYU86FWiwVXM3UrdczWW77TnI4@JMkZxYTYv8AV13VVLYF81MGbiCUkRN0ZvxTVYHFzuFqvdlqvNmCAVpPbRN3bNUlH0t4yO27rZR0edkAd7Xq/2/XQ2eVLu6CyrUuU6nt53UQPZ7XGykA@dwHKUuMgMrtemubYsLC/NL86O0WCC9SaruxXXP26AdZ4JLiOSdecO62APD2ErJ376ZkcN0FAPVNGI/JVGpTkjZwbmz4cwUkbtVTQa0QhwRIC@fnP@cPFD0Yspfbl/XLxvbl5fY2/G/T/dJ/Qujl9rV/eiyuNWkW8S1kLc2GUm8qTZ9RtMAvK3UMkZUmOOrwhHSNrFZqNdABl9z6b/NfTi/uYQii3JIBayG2xbZiaLYvG9sSYi/efvW/4K/59qvfR3mRwZ9REWLnOKyVLdQ2y1zphBuzH9vsMb9scOMv8GIIBjyuY6DNbzZuSCnKC5lV@Jp/Qi0VkjJOwG2n30ZLADJ7AUlRcIN5iYlaqSC2U@pcY7FtsVCkmekXrl3xePwfvdDKxThfnsEX2F94nvc4gtsCO0hc1TKqpF7UuY12/jmNX1h1/aNfWHcJsYsyMypAla7HOD2EGHSfmCTBLFXfHuEBZ9wfkVAVPa19IT3blXDtRJ/Q7leXrwvUDvZr5XKdb@1sPqGhsnV/C@4q/O9vQC1Ysw9pm/1adwRSb7OfzWtNtOcdkzqv8O/Ra/xjx138e/oK/9jxa/x7OsE/9riDf8ev8G@3g3/HI/y79wr/Hr/Gv2cD/Gt@LZtVq@LmOREmpZbVy82ZSASqxnbqza9N3HnFMuyG2Wv5n6rJ5sosGWt@zZjhB8srPLAf/@l3v/nNeK0Wl@L0AZCc6rhMTVaB9lAjL169GxdiNbapbqoZK9PNqB21Aw6TZVyWGWaGag@Uk7bKMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9cBvxlwGVm@iwzYBk7Y0NCiAXXpJ2ZoKsPjwH89QGQC38mntfrqJkug4IsFNTo24EIHlwX7abQYHEmvjBAv5RVOSMXzBZ@caUhvnjRVLZaWrnEZOxScrvxohlvoQlurZxjnbmx0XzRZjEPNNRqTGk2FU4TqC6R7PKy3d7/9H67reA803zsHC7@Dw9HUe@N/6ND5/GhM3Lg//DwEMaGUU/dTQEHvnu3BhzZf@zE6tWdZoX4esDbY8r2TrOeldBdSAG71jAs9Z7XAiI86xtNIX6WQOXiDPWL6udn1dMquc8CLzja1UWCIBl3@E@4zmAOC/SNM7hOz9BBPnSefd4MXdyhfH4GQZ8z0KzCf9Dgot7/Cv/mf1v/j5@xJEs0WsnE@eV2gq4k/iWT55fnl/69nkwkfE9iG/4wAPyY5fyyjk5KdA6uRiLZSl5e8jC4J5LbHGAditmuU95FOuD7sbBIKpbfEv91n1C0fzXjVQYch7TnfIbGUUysMn1xcKbZnGUyyWon@JoAbgPrF3Q6IVmlT8ltdhpq609/RF@M2ElSonyuWlW3GPdoOa1azQW@YqlaLQWezUSifP2qZ3bUAigYuVwyWa2CZycAmwEv5G2wNylWY024t@7c4YWUtIuLAGY2V0hl1AzmDkrKQ7GGp3d97np@cEgfWwDWko/hV044K0lk6FMt@DmwuFgR79xJ@J8Z39lN3rmjlTMXF2HIeAxB6lJQu90z3XYbw7MXF2JbpIMu5Tz4M6WLCzVTTqnxpOMmPsXvyEFRCUllH2p1KrUMPFvLFSHaRyC/vV3I1euFHIQUSvEkbpo3EP0W4BsX41Uxdk51UEtFzgHFKgZHDwDBWMYZgJ1fxqhBWS6fTAArTYKQdxnDP1dsiv7cks8ngTKXIk@plss8aZLlColSquz/1TZA7QYphv@hKJZN5baKW3dBqMU/b6VOgTy5em7U1MvauVHBZfPLatf/Ii8aLDDu3MmWgUSlTLUptNv3d4932@2aKIooCcENA4m7C2jHwY03qOb5cotTpFK9S82slvIM2pOnkeIwQ7ASEF3RtvJqCYkkmH20RwIkEUgXYhtsQ9DoiTehzCm3AYGgr0DhPbhYj3XYAC82wNVPZjKLLmYxHk/3bjdM5PDLjw29lBevMMQIL8EfhVneRWHGfvJod2//OK1tSyymPdjdS2tHz@7FVPTmF36KzqL/6f7u/cNnkOHJo/3do/2PDj7bf/YEwj12trgCpu/fF8@oa4X/jH0uvHRf64ahG1PDaJ9Np2ev2EvTbJvQmNYUKuUMXOYZbajLWF/Uqwq/runpL1/q7pgu9vaH3377w//u7e989@3vfPvt73z/p199/9vw@zH8vsuf3/035Tzef/rVP/vdt7/9OxD4H@D3R/D7yU@/@o1v8B/5/xh@/ykS9sf@L5KO/wSA9Ss//ep7P/rpV7/6A/j9S//3g@u/X/vJ6t/3v7X@h/m@97s3p/nuv4Xf73FYQdrv/jYPw@e19L/N0/3qD97@i3/H///U/0Pn77z9F3@MN9/zT3/wp//p7Tf/vaaV/vRfv/3W995@65tvv/Wdt9/6x9rb3/jXaiZ6@9233/@Dv/rD3/urP/wf6f/HdP@9d/l/@4N/@hf/61/873/xh/7vJ/D7d@D6yV/8exgqf/sHP8T/7/3B3/7RD/H/f/5Xf/sHv/63v/I/keM3ueP/@Zf/ht//@tf@49/81nf@6iff@Jtf/8nf/OYf/NX/8av/12/8x7/@73//r//JNzHwN3/yV3/0K3/5zW//5bf@@V9@86s192/feP/qHcK/@gcIeXc83wXOu9TrfUO@@rnw@ftQY1EK9BPo3b/89jd@CTr4v2Ds7bd/jK/6wG/N/481ldL8mPv@P@DQrtcZYzLggt@vv/32d5FE/wOQCP5Den0n9CzFcM93Fh4g62@tyPTLP/3qn/@IfDGjUqdtGZy7S1optQX6zVa57M/f/o4NZPmlZWghAL@k7yCHWor7DvK2tz/8xtsf/eO3P/zNtz/8FZy8pVw5vZuW1Fu2uyBh/h3SYcLCu6TDhF9g@SlaQ5NSX4CPfeFHfvHFF0L7QsF3yu5eQOgXFMQvxqPwnTM/KojDcHwJjV2wqNt3Znznph8alsxY48WLFm6oQhiWniLZYysQjfJZNksFS9JsFixNY6LZFl@lxjuFYvRMwNvif@GcCSy1WMzGb@CFS7pUEk/mF8GdQh6KSc1mkTVxknsIQx5CG8FUbq7MsAazWWoGSjA4oIQURN0DcbxWS2HGGscHvBy1eokRKqlUDeqNuXmedLuEIGb3CArkrKWesvZWbcYzphBePSBHSsCgp6KqialS7T4UWJvdZwgLgRPYFy9q9VJtVkdwbzg9UrPUPcIJgdVSs/ob8NcIJuQTYvffACqlWipVL2GBWEnePOk2b6Q8VY7qnmIpvw3gief5d@4y9qGolsQ2FxiRYDw13lOL1JgQkkN8M7XlV4f@Ayf9tojgG1SUXwrj8Tskm@5wcRUTAFxJkmWZwQ932HfYXYiecVApKhYeKQ4hRT2CekAYwHAxKCWkqH1T5IHyY7Wt974QGFZmc3NTiNXFrHgoE@kUhbknFXq5Ac/7oXpRYWKhLGKwQW96BLhA/iqVvxnHnbM444DZhyn@u3t3i30I1aTnIkxgUirr5JwYh7KdSokawK87KeE5qCUC9FMCdCHIsxrt1KWEdJoxuRbDOHZ4eOgjQQHPa0IKurmWVdGP@0XT6TQGOWQ5LafT/lOmJwXIvkOmWP8pbyJx6UPLTNNyVdCeqgyDWFTVUUEFxsA3b95Aq9ABqsoBKJ/MP0ul5UoUCQHctIZlzYM3grRcWeCaOVMLOcYStJoKV5IlBZZgW0mBH7vnSARXIq6VSnFKB9SXE1vB0bqCSt0BV1JjdUQ0uLhKWMong8i9Q7Z3@Pjx/qfH41aLCQZ9ONpoj12na3heAuN2P73PX7nQyoVkrNFA0McVDRmMsF/JEDM@uP/04KjCeKX9JkgQYlXaOPWrWVaF2Hj8@XbMP1ok4rfPHPEI75VF3RJaOQtZY3Uh1jVQs8Ad8SodKakKj73BPWcGOn1aFNNqATW7JK0fM@EXnSlDy5zcjAeMKXwRQ97eJgoI9XOJ9ibQCa1VEOp1/1AeU4X60f4xZDg@ZKqWkYX6F2wmY4HSpVC3apZhDybDTTzdJjYzYqROm41MGv@0bBbuaq6QVvPF1saGdS5hmU1qtnM8pngJ3nMJq/EBXEz4QGAfQBBcUAaePWT@wc@Dw6p/@g5tYCX4ETxRzcMwSwq4aM3BCePoVYXevbzTI8Q2vvxywup10K@lgwdCDLjFkAUH0CSzJw9laube1DUodsBYz/zMxI/ayT3TG1v6HIYOUCN2eXnZB0gHD5hW18jLc/TwftmlkA64L2e6ELMrldobNVcUtJNK5U1W0wQIELYUPOG2AR2ADgpsKfyv6kEh2WxJAU6liiI8stmsgAvFglAxBEanQd5kajWJ98FsTqXDIAJ@J0Gf1bTw8tPOPlykzWZ4WoyBCDaYuCwTxBV5nO8rCOQDouHxN/oqb9UfnJk7d7K4iJHNZcLVCqoxu4S22czmskhx4f@/got2b7bH9WxG3VbG4NTBmdtWdHB2wJnfVjrgNMFZ3lZMcE7rWTWzrUzrAhO2uSFMhnY2auLEmKHdXR4m1j3D6sv4/lBNpAI0cds3LF0PMtZ7tZ7Tpa9qV3uyiV83x7dieYZcTqw6Nppoq6GxBnqPmCWS58Kgdkbv7gpGbSCj1Q/X1i2hJ3ec3lz2JnML38SxHLcWB4kwHkQsoBsgiuDy1042m6s0WEseO@MdQcsXUw01A3MI/tRSWktvGDvFYqUndy1Dd3fylXwp3cOXfPwtrZ18pjKQv3j86OFkMn5q0Js/O7kyZEA7WWjRZqdUyedbjYYophpUTAu/Ccw5lLSxAcPa0HsSPHHDy5O0Ugsy90y3VovHd7KqJqmVbKZ0KSwIhzTHGtYFzJrCmqWR7uc@E6jYjg38ppLW0@Y5UaHS7/cvt85TC4@gn0vcB/S5lPR05zz0VqVIugqbpiVzEQkheh/Ife7v5VVELV8Sq43qwl8siNXWpXB3ZPRMHV/4aWbOr@cqAF/mUGNQUJMJlxXXcSaVjtF3XGORMKsWgoQcoesJcuJlWFwzgyWeXy@uEEk0O78OJZcXL8NcAVrC5SXQnRMbxgU3clqnc7ENtZxr7QMTarS2A/On2Dax5891vV6HRj7PFbVcPpfXsoVCvqjBZFPOFfIlGGaZQiavaQAgVy6Vi5fQo9/E6LtmbO886OcVtOye0CvcMmGjlXzzqWmdl7ISLz6RrF5ext4IMV2X6rWslhU0TdKyUlaV1Cz@3@LQ8P/d02vwr@EdcmU14Rhtj3wKsx/M2DZ7hDYMJg47dvArNgN2z@iuSbE31Onk8Z7reN7fI8093T7hUfdNbvAzjHqo46e8vJE5Ga5J8Ww8QrMlhvsPBmF/1AEEkaXxBPfg5lqOsypBkT17sqaWj0MT20AMbmMbkj89@OjhceR5vL@791AosHuHn96/8sj7ifLs0f6D49Bb5LFB1nwI4hf3Hz266vUfucNnT/tTx8Wf8ODwWW5xC4PwxVYhB9dyojCYgPg39JJ8CIIB6FP5YuBQBXwd4g7ouHd8Z76wcGbQ@Tl/a9f0wuP5/AXuinAcvMqrM@SWHYN1uXUaVLrJcpwvkqvFsiCMme2csWKG9RzL0vG75P0NCBzq@FqigXKpZWFPxKLPHNfqnZk9Y0N4jG9AllX8BjQiITwEIKNpl6wOgEyCdkh7@MVw3F3qWFODTcdsbSA8MAidrjkYwjx65gQJhI6uM/i97wX5jeg1uTlgwsugsGsx1vXkQkwQxT1RfKhP9FipUfVa43qmUrlzR33iiuWs6A2M/Rn0WPYMRpDuztMlcSKLD1h7gHsTVkF1xnW9DqpEAwTvsgaz705OM@qlTD7717/147/7k18f1NStZmYvs73z@FG@AjwVhFFG8qYvk8qknWjlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU0KHbFMsj2GbWkFkr5spou5cogSeTKEJsvF32JVglEWGWrAmDtLn6TeJsUHHkImgzfTWSvE3qSxfTQP2WiAXlEAXXJCb3ivWXWYBJkaoZliwwg6qzLYg8e7GUePBDFe@jBoxd7GVHsoSdfymSK90TRoJi9EkpFosPzlNC6mzjhnkzmHlB5ygGgYXRRHKJnv4CrYqJoomdv98EDLKePHg3zQ7ITHsM9VuApQjIbPSBoE4BXITRItsvLyRGi@@jBIjHmAY/ZgzhR/ChAB2Oe8mQcwMOgpru7onjAPbu7GLNH1c5zRD9Bzy5douiCB7q@KA7AMXBh0IliB5w4AESxC67uXIcw/P4z2s62J7oozjl5kECiOKPUevdEFNtBOBbzmY9NHqlbIY/Ka32XPGX8E0UtQBqTZUNPVhRzoScHdXv48DN9OOkZA37NXf7sQk0fPszq5my6/6Dz0UedwaDjznf3P3qKUXt7D0GimE/dzqDjZ@y04XIg195DTT8Zza9eUOuDdruiWyujPmm3c7p9Jao9bxuIIeR6BZj51wALGrX3IGrvYfuuvmo3mAC2ceyP4NnB694Invf0Do8KLoqi56zTEavY/RWlmRBQ5sd9XByOJ8BL7fRI77pOFf2zGsukcXVg3ihkWlWKYCOQ3TPVS4zvJ/Cu4xJO8nzemNUyrdqsVtT4caJ@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pV0MqE04@zuKTusIR6Z@s1S3ya3NFAjhebOzuS2FBbO5paqhSKz7emopis4H0nW6xAwkw8wxjeko1ia6eYj2QpFlO6olWKRRCsgCgTmNE7uLTSTiTODP0kmUR0UdGHKlBd2ZzqaVb7iVl6VuN4sXmyOqupVW4zlmWuweqhgfJpd@K4HOIAwM12MhXcSE@IarkkQvmKkkgmQ6YHarewOKr5@dePT46Pv4A4JtT9JYgn/IvqVd/70cM9@eAw8KFpcfkBSpWOK@8h11qK4fJlEHQMeoT8ECZR0MmCMHybz3UseZ9Ou4FoGkQEBmNl38ynfPxwCc7R0DnjJaMxhCrZirO7BkPL62aP6bU6uPQeSxBWTE@e0fTdrtdr7dqI7AVAFYNcnzAyS74Ac@Bx3EMTDZT9HN9w8yPatcxltVObxWYAp11jkvpi5PReaKlutYcG1@/V7mHmahuenapRM1zXccWYWO3v2DXGpran940nhovGRw4ON0GYwNfeEn1mJDdZcx9T76G2cSnVXWYvMPt0OkqAWN5JLgdFvEiaxNeDKp/Te5h40OKy2q@xxPNk9RV43U2W6Mn3kju5ai9xj7WTEJJ50X/RZxor5KqkMSQQEgwjog3WWU/W6p@A/MMBn1QqgIjfxicAE0sCsGaPIvTk2LysdmsWS0hsxpJEnlx1UGtg7gu8bUui2JKkxkVLqEvS50IdRmp1HtNr3rRDX@lgmY6qZQrVGYSpxVx1CA2rP59V3dp46hpVC7z@ehx/3VSvAjmBagDm9UXi7S99I7kt5Ws8rEqgLiwQOdpyuzar2mj3D7pELVuDiFQjl0mDBg63Yhpme62QVgvpbDqXlooYClN9Op@GQNBuQLZIWAmRMTGdmWVkNa0aajqReWH2XiTTJwkQWIhkLJmeOPv2dMQgBBoJeyV54amzZErbshi0gsP0bYm6KfCKKlYMaD5kYzM9RFBPDd2iHMmkxLJbCWszgWk2j6fj/UarUtmfjb8OUQnp1U4hVcykXieT1cRGsuYZr4R6VagjX6Fajzegz/pLlcybjhrQxuBSi1ql0ehgFYuZdDaThdqZ7YvBtlgXW@nMRkGFJrpkxDAY5xjR1TuUdRZh4zZK3ZYBTaeWtaog01JatqRJZSW/lc/w5TyeUxj7jA0pyRJNMXi1OhGPF7V4PBmv4kbChuivHAM3I04WB7Yav6PuiCCGiRWxrGGCBVOkt2czAXYgiF0KuHjBcmUhdi5cnl9u14WvCUf4TuS29hz/is8f7x7i39cgqAze0vPHzw6fHT4QmEJnNeV2rLpRlavtKngkuX5XiFUYAx7a9O0@KRuMve8p0NR2/Tl/NvF8P8AVyJYvyKx0OsswUWNjn6FNgR0Whzro7qihadlWQyvCrAd8NEgK@n4Vt1li@AaBXIfG8M4Bv@1UHV/H@4TN53pKCtb97zA2SG0KRJ7Y1S3V3dru4OlucMBsd2/1xuvmTME15ibI6nggLXYej8Uv4U@I3aWXAzX@ciCLha8H4taov6uRzRVYshxsOnwtfjcWj8dxdb/CvDcxarfgdatPXmjQZWK2EwSAtoSrUTCZ5fO4BB5TXoy9L7VS9vHBoX3ffWAw/vZVKdcW6zGWUSV8iala8UPzYnvjRIUekxWzJ@kYuxujo/BiuaSJGg@oxtiJFFcr6TQ0cnPjYsPBzQ0WHrl7Y3/8dcbG8WwuzlizFpvVcv7BbbVel9RtDY2pFVkFeH9fLUiZizrv43WKKGgQ8/aXfpCbbZfAr2VU8GtaPqXV6@qWxpKx8duvfh/t4pzvf7b7iMVxSfzv/uRHWvHv/uRf0amx@CUtk2vZYgxSolMtFGPn5@Pz80u4eFw@1opxpHLFJLj5lo0aqyuqlrVtu8oqiq5vFVM57a5dVfy0alFNxjwp5m8@FfMx78KP0jIliAp2hyhILGALxPafmnlNvbu9A9XZyea06ga0vxq@HMrCv23DK0Prlh6/uGAMPN16bzAwNXIpCqu8kdj2G2mbvcGdmTfSBntRq@MOv4qvlAY7F1v4ih3u3sXrKWUrzkA1YvXGZfWylaKtD1AhnxvGlt280mGbG/iOxXLQlg1/xpZHf5gpCPDAG/iMrZeemNhKKkqvFxpf2zZYvg69YksB3LaC7Qv@J0nN5Ntf@g1NK/zdn/zaRfui/YUGymS5XFC12M9@tj21p57Rq/8MMt5g8CRQCGnvBy2ToCNUJBk3S2r6uUKH3AUddmqj0MzTB2olKpIocJgD2@iRWimcopBEDdnmNvd6CUq2hfYQ0iR0k42rZFUQQuGUhGp30E0TDLaF5iobraRwLnyAUTATMxDMq8IHC1AQMIK51@m2PWvqjumNlATlU1tpdgeyQAkfoDnDDbLj4LNxCfiZsnU9K0fZI6qRQMVGhuehcUSYgYQPIItv09eas7GOJkcwpWnDvCFjEsKTInoNKLsFZVs8Q5tCE1R7niDNOHY8kw2Ct/ABSBJEBRMEDGZuQ4IqcKEPgABQh4QP2GyxbZZNsnMzlaouLC9e4tF6tA2pB@YOBMyG0HpoXiPIXMV0EAQCP35FEvuF38Ig20UCAyAcBt@Jr4HKgNnJhxIb2SN5Z1AAi2x/Jahq7M6dBVa1mtlLMqoRwj8xx7jgRe1gr8YVgAXq1oe9iphmaNOyGoSG3Q4oniJ0oddJ3JhlNZKViei9FAT4f@dOiz3ySlNRRBUr4LcXHxVdIBlkRrLzNuyy7RpTtWKShch3AfcuIUVvnYc6ZHP2oax9EUReAoY/iwXfaAEWdRxdRPT77VV7Fwyk7Cl@IAOtnnFm4Nup4HbNkNUdTILcYS6oimlR6r7pgnZDRwQCk4qJrJrEbAsTlIQHHX7XcgzPoOeT@KBcmJrBU0fTgH45G2TSqOtAg3pjxyZbgmTrCF8AgB4BPMo3w8bRntpn@EElv20ocxQjj0ywYc9HjMk2In2JmvLiHn3HBSU4oE2aGQOZdUc9ppVZgjoamYuzQ3BJykQId0BURhp3LGMEKB0ZBr0i5lUUZQDi07RDNvMem9Cvhg9MmG9sT/E/@q2cmSemcowfhJCcPr5Jxi2QxFDiwuHHjwP49uksxzlhlnli8LXhxJL9Fo@BsgDybhoou/gBYSt4zkTLpnG1Qk3zVPArwqPInaV0JO9GYp68/syqG4k2tugFTT6mix/0PtXtCH3puhB8/dibe4EFKLJjBH45ZLmGb/ulFkerDqFRI8G3ZVUjM0oy7jmME6CtBjag0CmMXeOUoaYr4BwDTLMbWFPBUQy1/YAmABp7MLLQNOTEraANIMDE7SW6MPR8Bm@zD1lWEzAhN9DlG9MCGNj0tWXoEAdZsR7epAcNI9NCO/IVGJ2jHsSh9Qm/@2H@oHejm8x2Lro32/DB4aRDZdUYHxaBJx/x4OjA/kxV34DIAmC4ApONhJgCsCkxKXLQYf6r2XlvF4iXVNh1SGmGEHxSAxQSFXRkOfT99cWXjwSIuKd73Dy@bzjy7OxMJmumU9eUDQ@/BuQ5tm4p44EJArSjTIzR2P/uqonf2/bhLlwS/wiYPB6Od2YoutbKd@b8KQh9r@af1knE@14cJ8dT/NjNYESWz9DkmEcd6oFJH8rqJvzDQ7z/aa30edD/Ktj/pFL8EoEwhmBm6Xm6mwZg6U73JN0/61X9iFMakAAcWtEIAtHGsBt4Rl7gMsf9MIUzQT4aRnWsE9p9BUgiX9ZdFM1rGKScB17fPzZnkMk2ztiu6@rzBMUnMTV24MScxB42h2mfYsAJ0ww75wZvzVlj3lrKPguzw6QWnj1w0ayZcH4zUG79GONnPH4G8TMeP1sUGhTbmLW4SIZBl1gd7PVoDTNIiWDmQZpLbil4EUOQQfpmKgeBKedLYZfw69Yod0Bv7oN2rAUdA/rEGAhuJJTG82aj2bI942yrlVIG0NlFIgS0OIButIimZ73QjdS3Tq2x4y0F2WgEFWYlH28M6g793sD7CtYxbCDqGJxeJtqtHIz8QxJcIPArDBBQDoNIFA12JwkzWQ2tbVMkdJyGuKAxR6zhI9Mi6cuP8sNAXOKk54SNAmpFAGF4WCVAE2JYMHL4t98C7vC560CaIK1En6saof20eCsOlLwyVDivqVIjRbCSpABNIDuKq7WrVQnioSkaV6Ii1bz02z@K/sZ7o9@HcbEae@qwfMKoCtGhgkcTQYTwhwtRldVrkXYFDJQt3TJcmLn2uXzqz9ZQzJYSqBm8HKyCd4YftE9EGr@b5O1DL0CKtlgJu8K8VoMqzmt8WPJxEZCUEzzM5vnZ5kFH8PNzBgIwMiuzGX62WTTbrFbjjIPN1mQ7iyA5IyRnPAtPPVuDZMvPBtrTQTC9YPO0QDrFs5MiwFP5NApi0Fhk@FV73AZ/ibYdcSvBL3PBc6gX@H0IRWzsZ93WytIbEaQjTOsKAOyI1wD0@GdkK8JVhqdKoS/kUZyUAY/iPr8bcF4BHYxYcJXbP06EnYx0YBD4xRTNAzB2xVRDEFVaFMa/DP@J6SAw@KnXAzPLKdXlwEz6yt8/SGALKRsZoBHpQ83kkCGjJvPM9g2HRmWOGH5xfeiAVNc5c1hihbAN4crUz6p0LKejjHQ8zoIfl@Sh8nieDPQH3FBhd8fORJ84uVyFK00mdbtV5XOdwRzYDn6TJmIDHWS9nmN4dnwCjdp1BrbpGWmG5ilPDF/tMPyPMghROdl3Op4g@IekuBqLoHm/QlG33cbPXbfbCTxzmKyEZ6jpCCJ2z3hcQP0XXJH8wJ58oIfjhNN5aXQnydthokF/P9ux2T1JHI79SFwl3WXAw7og/0PsECQY5jkLzZGMhaMo3Zkk6EMUQ2fkDEDqm3qygLmvgD9YwEaE9PGYcEkzHVXaSuSzDjRKEt20nvSzfvLeWdknWkJPhvm1ZQBLxEgz9yqNkbLuiuLaa4vj2YLyjt4f36Movkc340ta@FWcuWpe45HvV3Q2sYAACRdoZG9HA6sOfKt3DZ0lVMJglKt4hndGsUfHxXqI6S4k3fWTy33oH@nQ54EvRPyzdfS/uQGD7Pvv2nw6DHt2NAd@M8Ljkwn6jJgX7IwmIPlBEnnP9eLCrn3/HcuCtPgFxwcoQoAYS4zLRjvHMDDHoHZ74XJxAPiWPo8ntK71ezq2VeORK3ByT9PsRFvfRPfbPcPS50Yv4adMR@AGNX4KChvxq3erODI6YnoO1/USMHclw1iYxpHoPFFlTZfR06fJ5PpuxZOYYe@hlXLC8GA9/TD@GmvGJb4aX60GPSAej@Fy7KmJy5/j@XjOTelb/BtSPh/l8w9vSTTicDtBgA589lTTi2KTN7HPp4mwSu8wI4Rp5eUqo6XrACIaQrrehu9HottrCo0byVQLWllY/ojM6hY3b2rxSK8I@iTfZXq3Lnlbp3vnPhfpahzYgoXtvd8Ucg0yHubodhNRiDzkxhZz7Gs8AcNonc5eM6u0VzDUMCdxuolJ6jbJF0kBNeMDeOKC02fwRIADY9LmHSqoG65p@Z9lZBQz0scRqcUPASEdoESoyEnuoxFJJQRuSH5@GZbZXVtm91qZ3aUywxGwXGQkkdBdKtJvBWyem5rAMvqTNdwZo1B3hsdNbBsu29FdXK04j5vxiplm8dN4BRhy3IhX9hPAlOO9eOU@Obx45YgcJ/HKJ@BYjK34RbwSDAtM4IKXHHcx3Gfh6O/GK3uJ5KUw0U8MLyhXjlfCNoU0O9xLFAFSYL1BasQtNtvxqzlxDZjYSKhMM@wxXhrVJ1qHSdMvA//8s1D0wRiMxDXOLUrMUkxdmjQiMwYvB6aN4IMEK0ZyxZ/N9w8f0GGoMAkWkwIdL5qHwIMYHosvMyOOGMbSjgY8AUHkm5XVGLHITPaO6PilQw@lRl4un6gnkzzQS1B8AxK3FoXQt8D8/EF7LYPgDfhueGLmdXheQycojjDCPdnkCrSQqC/iN1QK23oZF7/1oy1Ea93LiQBbKUjCW4nARng6yHC0OYeFjZ3xciehWDx0b0bz0KIcH5TYe69kI67gj8w10RTs1wwZQ3TwJ2@qTiQforbEgjCykWnxURbOC8SLMWrB6yKSKh98gEKE58AIN7on9J21@76T0nF2k6a5Yt00FOTlRRLnWmaTkFlGo1RTfcJLD5XXfTRV9X7qa5BzhmstCQQQyRmWwvmr8x7yu8Pl90CgDohwpYBVgvXqqfS6eH3jLHsFc2tR7PUGxMg0u59cKRyFJSxIDtpBRDK/qa9dE/HxyAcX8nmhIfQr0n5AtlAnuIVuV3ULDgulBPd0OfBEg8ATbT2hrksk1qkcCC0yluTD4RUPMV1U7WZcecVXNTHG0Pq2bv2/3X3rVhvJku5v6inSEm5UplSSsMEYIWwBwtbeGDxc7PYBrC6kEqhbt1YJg3zpNTM/zguc@T@PcF5l3mF@nafYJ76IzKosIbC7e5@zZ02v1aZUlRkZGRkZGZkZl989wKP0ANuDB3jcgdEUyWWWj676bOWSzG0S2/IGIrW0pkSQ83VpPMzJSxL3fHUbX9vSi/3Gwfb@3u57WnSfPn3q6jV6kuCHWYuz1ngdF8hsWR2vBzO2LUsekiHhshvH8dHlYDR@cNrP3JIlIqxJGQioFcN@eo67WpZZ8nxq7lI9KWtRVMP6JZkGQUoqQdUJsGR3NF3HRJBwnHsUaCBGvSV6e7xbczntT6PRD3pho8HLl0kpq1cxDI25EXf/ln1QuIpGnNZZclZdOw5Hh1Db@@rdq@qROnpVUzvHW39V7/eP1bvq3hECA7w53tytbyn6v7Z3WFNOyo4S@f2woSS6bofNEElb1VKx@EQx5K3BcCJyJ7flyvvDoKdeDZohrqnWo6D34lJ@@P1wvCG1arQdneAMs8P5HHudMewtOAEhbWOh3LTYURCuAIrKntOetoc9b2/Q6rQ7VNbB3nfYCSPjW6a6HRpBkrfGRdoTJQm5Btl0iHOIwgLrmqoHVB53NwQmEPsrkBglJDlhy1eacPF/v5uCR7WD14cKMSa29ve260f1/b1DtbN/QD/fvK/vvSR61g@PDuqbx/jEBV/vb9d36ltVfiEIFH2F4A8/X0Xje1HwUZyp0vwFN9/@kIY//pU@9YYGr64DdpmM1MJVH9KnE3Q7n8LWQtm5iqC@wE2TrwpUbr568PItrfkq/BU3nOYqmO0PMscR57@cL6p1bo0mywbNt7KerrTs5Usu30f0JgopcMIyB4XI8bOnDHA24ml1QpXZgo0Kzr4ldgTPZQOaGnpAsAHKGKxUFKeuWljw1hnkBrXW7A4Q6FNaEyNC/QNVXxhTk7LDFNO2MgAKZ4d6H@dBpXL8gvieXizpZscjKaAexy@kgHoiL6CK1mE7opZ1iavx/hXEs1qRFz/3hjt8Layexi82A97FrmqcZNx4SAMVp/5DJI0uJyiTUx5Oosr5prlKxOWRvKvblYkRStpIkolylci2bVQyQ8KmjasGbfYm2ZjxlbgBdkJBexypXMX11RGMg8J@R1LDXXSDvphAJaY7zHtqFUGLKhtafYhTqrH7yHDADIh0jmk84nrbWisMv7ce1dy81WKgbSQ5rakxQfsWApu3EPgjYAhQPrXTafJKxV6sADNoa1bORQPiSJzb/maXJ3ZuXTXDVAVttZX7ufPpk6uJ7KX2ScZOkbGjIfoUjkit5KvM9mBEc5zFKiehghRsXg6G446MYS7dA75x4mWOSmNho9Z@MsTVrYEO0y32B32r0XPi4jtaPSem/J5WmePl7jwWX0l2YuJ8WoTF7g7oBOeDj6F1d@bhEuk6xPELKcJ8V47Dz8mYMRH900lkx28KSU1XKxvbm6f5337ykNlUxIIkFjZGh/ifGBNt0fTgez42WBxB79IzzWSki67OUVvb4GlpiVlugNE@8LJD@7oXjXL8TcyNb7@Hg830e3755UtFauUhmXQ26ugyl0g3T52YJj2uc6a0CYglOwlZkvU588ZjmLG8fgGnGowCovD0IUewb5/K96ZFiOnd@VWbJItOu6uHO4bvqg22qEhylsNZxh6PwofcZmVxwy0kBiXKImfOiGjPQC65rmWWwuvVLXDb94Mj@f394FbvxU6Wh98FbfteaL8Lt/zi3bBkWbJgfT/Y3@4BK4vbHwJLfffuBiyL5G1oMafHzOnNZ2Nr2vtb/OnW2PHcIzBYe3GCEgO1Wrvq8xW1CZudkwquDSZRiA6PtmsHByoj@xOqS3IPW4aWFoOA/UC9SaxtO30Wdn6sNMWb5Vh5Mm9SFm2x@9I9k3km8e4QFVoH8TQ9YmGRBOdud25E6umVhVUItr5ngWgol8bus5FB0YkG/JX2gIRsMmhWB52Z3czK4tOJbCNwTTdPdGPbhp8trGXtRjLb0cQGZNsEBRfwLJk9fu9EP14z7YiChbhF6HCLNGlab2ifcEgND6mg76dH8J5hMUMKI3tRsLOGdjD8KqY17D/PUMxIooSLLmyJda0ca9REP543ag4bJGIZCGDpqT@KRTN9MCKe36zbA@omi14uvQSRkon0pi9srqDqZ1/1EsbUiNfJSqyQ23NtnrE5MVie4XRWwy7fXeghbKFXpsXDdFMkbe9tKv/3aUpWiVRLhuYzO2M@EuSV5eXH34I93QtTPf9nYcsaMi0/x70h7e8TkNEk4uN94tz6nme@JwxwD@nEtN5MmKmKpOrMWFNSfefFyMaPcJFzIUIGseaRMXa6VVfdTOE2G7qsSDZ0LnKrD9YUjjsqs@YW9b/e3xwE8jfbe/D725PJhkIwHfwKq/zXg1EUJl55VnwX6xWc49PvwtGoz8XEn6kHKDl2Y7rX2Y697cTgVXqFj3zfZvekrb2TxOzWM2cN3AgfL/pIEo3TvfL08V6@VLa7ulPfralHHHuynTqLzIwyriV7HnT69yHAMpjPJbB8sA/fw2iN/iccPAOSyMTefDmmjftN3JgipDWfcOYhbRaqZWtpevTbUTPoIyKIl3kYqYz3A1XkU9ja/o4762S9WE7VJ@SiYT9HtbxM3s9wVXqHA11ASoOQ0cR7a8GCp4axlIR7zcUA9lG42Apv5PSMLSeDQmm1uPLM4d71vbHXO3l25j1qVjKKFt@g34uuRtetXy4Glx/bqquGP5/fNCefflVq@Yl6TG0t/SABgEsrlQLHXH1K/66qZ0XmXI3gcw5mjKTFvmRzVWpBJfvw8gPl8gNvmtfgITHFpepRz3AhXOzGld7JylmlXymWeyf9szKc/MaLlfFiaTGHFz/QKkoyRm7mT8ZnWFPtU9ew/1EhzCZnDdWuIYpdQ@jN62DUGexW916mTuOgAOAITNt684G6JIiegzUbfE/8fnid08dkngLHOlCQnDn2CirB@Z3Pk3Ec0@oQZjQqHmmz0Q3/O3GduaJ/NRwP@IuJqAjWUl86X5w548ZU5BMFKnLSMXEX4V9AcJIyOVwMyduJWFHnS6KuleA76VogTlCTxWHmNJOBTyEQ1b5cJ2dO5IdB8xJIICP6F66m1tc5PzqxWuTzKR5MOYIRO0wUz/CICxD6M@TbBjTBmnvEbh8OdR@/S3iQN3xGNWY/GTaQd1hTxBeYf6vP7N/E9deJAEL4OdG5fH3EqTUvUiTFd5APFxDqLL3xxzUD3CplUObQWcCW9ioJcLYUZxqhWU0mej93DXIKreg/3YN8iX/d6kZc3pXiTBK@p9a/ItCSh5Q/beBPN6mWs6rlTTVT2CLF3DepgZMu2h69DmlaTdRW2O0S0kKLuYQceGT/Xt3@Ytx@dII2z2Lk5Xv@1vd86rsv3wWppJRPC3xSaM0ulMl@Tsp9VZmkmHerrYpi5cWnkW76pJIkZcv3lY388aDRSQpvxEMpXBl/WE99yFtfPswYffnyIFUnZvD4@4l81/y9pEc@xjJV9kW6ffx19ACFbDyrbU2muNTvd7rPHZ1MW38Bm2WImkpJdU6XqMykqmgfTC1OSIPDOT9P241KAmWxZCQOz5nMxvqLjK@VjOe5aTTEi/HWxJoxRywqcZuLTLgbdlikdvjzAwsEwwSjKTNzN0zlia48scCi1APTrHhB3prg1LXpKV6BX@QX/GMmexo5Uy47@@OcYH4jnRfv5jSBWOg@yMwmU1qawF1EXupO3bOKJG1PpiHOFhJ71ilw3GYoPthtHIM/iOWELSiMpLhF9/iLpnRSoGTY964hxMevzt8Kj5yXAenYw254o6rYZgTsheWkHNzHYTSOEBiKg9ZEV8NhF7eOrPBdswu1DiuytIzrlgSitbL7Th2WPVLew5N2SKdKvtoH5GsYiCQfoquLCziTwQN2cA3RihOXzth3qv2JHGjQnHm8JG7moULwDRbA3c6FjYSMnMweUDoaBs3Qd0hHi0j7caSr7Y5OM8rn6fAbQegxWtLWHOefrjrNX7Ze4j73aan4uGSR7KO@Di76j58kDlZEJPNhCdEDl0tPHMe6G27K3XAeAD21i4X@LfFm@DHs90OnSisGF4xIaY3C0cew5TvOQRhfAgMuWBk3k/DDHlyNmnK4Q0pXQMwIL@HIk@sw4jD8xfos18VNvivzHFxaJbfNNNQfOy0Q0HictAe4HeYLC4QJEHqgUi8cE1EeuSqNEt89a1xYd@nhIIqogTgn1t1ETIb@YNxp0sjwSZbTJVByDZI01m9NYULtNbsBnIP9WQjAPSahgEHAXCXdh4OjL81/Fw5Kd8zcsQdmZAok/QY8V2i6h6MOSd@EwDwqXM3CnQb46FX9UB3u7xy9qx7UFD2/Odh/W9@ubavN93zHjYtyjsOrXu3vknSJb9Pl1nyfXmSqh1Qzwx@c6t57VfvxzUHt8FDtH6j66ze7dYJG4A@qe0f12qGn6ntbu8fbfPtOENTe/pHarb@uH1Gxo32PWzXVnKSe2t9Rr2sHW6/oZ3Wzvls/es8t7tSP9tAYbvWr6k314Ki@dbxbPVBvjg/e7B/WFDrmbNcPt3ar9de1bZ/apzZV7W1t70gdvqru7k51dP/dXu1AsZGA1cvNGmFZ3aQtLFrifm7XD2pbR@hQ8rRFxCMEdz11@Ka2VcdD7ccadad68N7TQA9r/3RMheij2q6@rr6kzjm5b1CFxmXr@KCGaEmgxOHx5uFR/ej4qKZe7u9vM60Pawdv61u1w7JydvcPmWDHhzVPIS8iN00wiFr0nZ43jw/rTLf63hGtGcdvYO/g0iC/I8IQllWqus0EhhkEektE2j94D6igAw@Ap969qtH7A9CUqVUFFWBRsXVkF6MGiYhHdjfVXu3lbv1lbW@rhs/7APOuflhzacDqhyhQh0HGe2IdavSYe41xIrzkkZjVMZzr8XCq@o6qbr@tA3NdmjjgsK65hcm29UrT3EecXusQpTPAmUHQsw9W2rdffQwRmfL2iczsM5o4YtLW/naNVmQd2iqTfDimVWd1KpSS/Y1Wmvgj/UyFrGmF51cXjU6/PYCPaVxNDj560YWHbD8uUqWcOvckvdLnK1whm2003lYbtNE9bDRc73tqptD4Vg19DH5fKVf3EXkUsPPGwc/amtB9PUWojR/0RScb6uECAiWF@j@I6VvQC11VKLRCXQ3O@wBsjo4iuTa5xFUKiUZ2dkSOl6RJPpng3x3NDlwxZ8D7zQbOSWEZyYUGEf3T/5L8kMXBekHSWY67CgVsYhmNzqfQNCONcEgE/kdHJOi0uUk/CsNfLnJFuzns@f2LwaCVc11Th8uOaR94kXO/Uf08vJiqnp@uz8jytbNOQRCZfTerMPH9syaZ0uPij7hnOfzTGPMf12AjMR9waspN8WG1PrTM/SDVYZHkKR3aAu4VPMjQ@V5Xf6y/w26uuPSkPPX@Vfxe5hbsBRHDlha8E653xn9enUkBmmAci4NI0tERMgoFq46xN4kLX1PBSxS67rRg@UNr9WXI6zqRhBTZq6Brt4nVeNS5sbEnOfzyoPp683hnh0QnsH2yuvx0pezEYbd@9OTve7TDYWY56tiQ1nHS0/iTNUu2SPHhmWJF@U7Ynxm4UEBBxG83g8YvEechtttIWzJBkKG7ERIe9WGilwlBh4ziABwPHMOvM2emZoBcqqsuetMLbljFD0hXYh7QxizdCY/aDf4B7Hj6myked0gzkGYxDrxLnEu7C5Z7mR1jKsqbGw7cgyJ@xvCxhHGLacBHXWw/C@9a/qV52xrFSEwZMV952LkmIfFgGgtl7Cr6MrPfcJwRfQDM0cPozY@a3@jxvQ5wx@HugmhcHR8SGXfimjinTg6jdadPNOQz5NJAUDXT0rrCKb@rkeK5p4@T48Ag1mxgVJDgBTa@acDlOI7IdJNsAftiwVWfhVMRvANwyppj9W/i3Fnd0VDKJn6I/m2iUiiBFQc5Eapdx204psj7OI6FIWeKTH@KHgz/H0iTGfDXacdJ0BNqWUEAv4uSDFVoRdtXJkrn2lw0WLcbCTXtV@8TMF/tgbmMO6Zvb27Ev4ZIoEdnYl6857CH7dwMAoDJcbBhz9/YJO0yoK3Ti4yrq@OepN/sDXNKrxVmqbgFN79y5rHa5Zm7FfxwlStnTVaDu1RVvZCN2znPetoyTW3l1cMoI@BcE/@j8IgPQOIJz1x6KVar05xV1LPMyAEdaslacFpxxCRSS7/eeWv3SFkhMlOyX998GUIR6A3gc7ufnFhkoMQ8Nx1xkVdidcRR8BBMHNtkLD46ZN05G2J2Q8B52OLDEOQeGV9jgegKdA7Vl0BTuYdsKIJGEqvDJM4gxK3rE2l5Wb2OseeTSXBojP1xX@LYh3KqZUr4EuBDY2i7y/vqdTAhlLvf121hscKjw4EH20U0JscSuj7yrDQHgxGpjgH6TTh6nYnrq3f60CHsR1cjHb@Q1rPOSJ9IGKWfmoHaJLt3XmYkgDyjFnXG8FZo@cwf3KVeCAtRCU9yk19ROWJew6Mb5tCxc7NYUrn15Ms60YTDkjIR19WK@vJFSglBdcjQkCnYieLNBdtscju4d4in3/Vg9AvWfqhA/VbYiiOTWiD5LFAGqd7nGI/NsXR9OIj4RIOGAicgMSVKcpAWG6rSGv1Us5O2a8ok0TERu5R78vvbiZnUWEtRQwnj6taJ@VbyNJig0pIODRoHCy0tLTMqszZcX@/cjHG00PS1tcqc9mORsiZKROWhUR3xJHIzfnqPJ33IX3kYYfbQG9xxaxUUCENnxb3qbTnH@MGm4F0nHLXsM1HSZFrBEMdvvPUZ9JkXzdGhDvvXDMZROKEdQLPQuSkwjEbuL4PLfmNr0A0uOoNOQPs0xIC/EYmHxwk/YsAuRoPriFMI8YeWVag1SZ4lvoyEYcPv@F6ybIXmisbhMGebKYxHk@qlhIngk3MYASZZSJm/h9Mx0uI6T5aTSk7a/5Tt8Upu@c66j0uzKsuNPgBoAbcxZUEhPqRjdkyynE/Ltwqc31fAwvFc5VXg3mGxl8L4GZGIr2FSGBtkbpkl2J3AzuxOjE9aN16LYxCOEGgp3A6RDifK8WsvQGJnkiLPYSmwpkqrRauq3KLcIA4hHiZ3k3vp6T8Ye0LgT6BfejyLW2YxAou4tom2FMl@RUcZJVzYPLDDMpolMUmxzkWnb7kfcgaKm2mo6c@Tu6jBlj@kFOkwe7e4EjMyRxsfZLrLNUjkNCYuFpUFteBy3A6oINVxrng3w4bfsp/lyY9LXDk5g2Da0pBzFtJ3kapJVELq3CnzWhtlian87RmztPS9ozZFwMoskzMrhXMuYzQX9kDpyPqKa63BiIRxZop62tRjIRoPhgvfSb07ZcfMyGyzaN103W8aAguzVWixfNRi0lYmeJyUnWl8ppgmTTG2NCMewvaVn2M2nybiTaWB@VZpTL5Bh7tolthNxYtKPN4tmftYFD/CotcsNPGUYtwRpLQcvz9pUMcbd0sQDVO2Vw2WGA2IjMZEHi1QU2SKqfT9FGLu07hP0aNFlEO7LaKdPT53EnXaSM6EPDWfUkEuQU8EbofTJsmlYRvGFwgTJxpuLKRihfPGm/BVXil/jiDD@CAAoRWH@eQcSk5wk8Ga4iPODtDONWAtVIIkoqcN28IhDvofE4yj8uvDHW3x0JjkS2dlgXQTQ6JdBZe6D5LxN6efJ40bhnKLFDTFZ5Ai7tEt2XT5/b36s32hcgRBavNnbelb9NAZVy0SNvSP/alxAx04aUrXTM2o9ERosGiguUC7lItuKNtVaH@dkXA8rBv0NKINhLzO4c@iroFw3ivFmNqoctOaoIiryS2zzVX5DamSMJT8Bvn1VBRVlzeuBCAUjKl@pUQQENaUscelAIfesTkvhageI6pYKWFa0kuOiprYec74DqLqAk@WrRLFWSWe2TDyM4GQYjG7TIII6SyziyRQaKGbiYtV4uns/iQlSCE2vC8Up6HQo5KmYTxyQkBOGF10E4lyUlJeUXMwf3yy7KY@xvzNX58Vra/F6a9EnxjDk3xp@utqMfU11ezSUrpqqibRw7VbTX0kUrg2wrFU@HP/sWuKHfI8tgm1NhkpLUPbZyOhN@0yad/m/xypdXbKNjqGgWd7hpvtV0NSrKSCst8fgF0t8JUBYrf/6d4ay1SDic4VwHHpjLNLTjaErLFmsNSjW9jpmkh7cYACs6cdtNXbo52dVNjX84kxNOqFo@VisQgmPreD3xvbahwldQaFdOlC@6rbLQyv/zJ6e15g2R@GnBJgzeygQxoSmhSRPxhdSGYI4EBFUTqvHVmx179qt@0UDLihxODRsElJHQ1B8QLUiY1e3h7xARCD1AvsT@gg@veTimffdSCKpoZirqGoNkyCP2bM7RmRBy/asM@Ob6oYGASzsWaidcutbHzGCoLMJjxYHL7Y/ZyYJ2dehd3uwFPvkIQYkQLmvk5X2NmxKxSlCG4Y2bv3KuJ4tJ4KP3a6ll8xiti8DnBmYTJ5JkxceMTGPwgvajfDXObkQ4aWFeryIrq5iPjUnspcZFwdLP47wAofEtrfVboXDHNNptN0YVrq9QxOngijxyVv5t4nVcTlMzFNs2@XBlFno@tzsAbqusu6gIllz8PLPbmjeEzczOlNqQ0aFgWGxgkxV76vBlzN/nFi8eO43f4@qchpAGRgf5dElEwof04g8h0Az0A9/YieiKL91zxN652pgCKi4CBZx225gwoNVHCch83Kr9e5arWq5oeLi6pa3aSHfF5VN6tqGy82N9U2/d7E7x8qS8vLZZG52@5nerlpXn5VmwSDTzgXm5ejbfpJ3yrwG4O1NoZ4vlCZ98rzjcr6RjkqnFQ34dZPT//5L//zP//1fxWq@se/48cm/zj5EBfyfb8w3/w8/8PXMn6fbJ8tzJ@fzA/PFi7K4LK/cdTwQX2cDxLzUX907mRlFbDesh2p2Wdz9BldVZkUgL1g9AtJlzWVbUaFrH4bSeYolrHZZmi9D@FHeU5beJN0YHorT0hkCegEx/E0Os0QBni03hAlCRfYgUp9uVsxB/cIBxMXiG9VsjoSD@usH0P4tCSRFOCLSytWvtOPwj5OwD@yzivdc5yA/nbGDc2/hQ@vo4vNwY16dJpTj4rqkaceZTL8p7TyjN6684UOvHOlGG0HMhmPviRXCzAzVFGHFT3eP3CunSlyO848p@wBJBOmgguLF5wX7/7YWUYSrkUXzhzycCo5IuFLJlTJfp7vf6Vh@UwlvmZSrjasKDT0LoYbs25U4vGFChREYgiQtNwTgqwNqEnc9LFHMp4K5o0ea4ezCTFgkPXg5Q7Pe7ygtWi@r22eU3sppDli83l5i7WxLM7QjDa@SPsJAnyhItvJInsSLmQXHLHytnrJ3RQvbLt/mvnE1mESjo1tulT6TVlMINbcNuHm@9qvRRtyy/WKynTi6xWrqcy07bdyrCq9q@64M9TuCtw6JtTnuLWvMpMwogxI4EjM/rXbM4wPCkykqKlhkWRZE9UaoOsyE/raNZ0G2PXl5sgiQuFDjub2l6m57RbYS8Swg/AAIxWb8rWDTjfSUVdGTOyLYHSO7IBBmxOqjeXejM/zkE91CuNBO0baZ8hscp7MZ@pKdjgKLnqBp7J7g6NRMKnTskWaz7jpu9RDhGACEph8uulZ3TMIS4/0kDBF4q6w5RCSF3QnOj2ajG0m9jnBkJqpoMOuYBKk2IkpGX5JjdUUHROu/h2DYKN8S3jHt5FaxLLkhaWRhpSx3WZ4mt2aOo5pwZ478cTJOIJqPDMNL@hKV1hoe3zxS5K8ixgBuu2M9gLUrggrz9A@VqeLsB@kFqdh1zGO/oWyknUR85lTUYo1kmPypJaSjHfAivTID@koELI2mXBGzlwuN3ca6XRuWXsd4SDfsS1@IVCdOAEdJzBjzxB13O@IsJxaoZIcGL6qs@U/QWh3gwvCb3IdTMCKp9nc8wcF9@TDaf/sUe60/@X0k8uYaJFsVtm8yurLbCOx9FyhlbHgpX4aq7TIhBo87acLnPaV@LBYJCBECrmTD4WzLwVC6DSLlPSnWSFIasiASeH@9goAX7iFZjaNRSHrzLmPXDP4ueclV9Hayn8xhvLClb@EhdlU8jE97XNGbQLFfrq/XonLSVRYXSo@WSo9oZ3QRXiTH4VXWG/z0dV5eEOqRITtLC09p59S3JAixNebKCjTyxvqp6Q1Ed@TSDspaRGqpzm348RsRXV84QkqT1TmcKlwcXHjMgEuH7Hh9xSxnCnLsaDEdNDivhzWz2jQQztBBLk27R0iHAkrA7ER4SPUPCCb5Ct3cahrpssC@zn5aguxWxkIDW8ha60W/UE/r5U1118oQ4mG10x3tbhanJ6jt6ZoaobOa2Vq4YEqbTx/@h//tv9rdpzdWCq8G9HfcfbX7MpqVh7pgX49Nr8@Zjey6yi28jU7KdAemB6f/sf/pvobfyE4@DJZp382lg2slUl2I1/hKl@yGyv0UFpaonb/zz//M/VhXnZsyMU63/AUI1Y2FNkK@sy79F3V0UvZli4kYoUdswBDLAxpb04/YBh1s7Ra5GO6rLaq@BjqyFfGHkUv8WyYNWZTITnJMPYUpBlJhQoayAtIY0LRVpbthjHbAPMmaKqfHvorEe0AftLmHHGTsenGwwgmQ/OyLaIBzEmLtJ@Xh43i80xs3rGWMTYlZaNCYmunZe3q4zKxw5tBOO4001YSZrr2msF1eO6DD/2wdUV7qn7UHfw8KnwkluyVllYLbRzuF9iOuzBkSPnhxP9EiqBOBkQbQzY69dSIRmDQQwgvj7MFkUK/E99JmXySpGUPw6acYaVzElMR8fHz5HoY3fETVTrH/5ICj8yZOhGklSvttE819w/WVGYxLijleM/rAps3bByrQ2DkxRp2yLLJd7gPOB00/fGrowt2QuJaiLouRfyg1WoE@lvOmcuYVGmeM3cZdoeVTFvCuyN2Km5MNP1FzbwTSr6DE4R8ngUdYPXCcUBb9EqG32A/nrSAMCn6rjUOFZeQta3L6l19q8JZV@5p@lqavqYRhZaQtBPzjBWNTdnFRLZUcFQ5Chu4UpvZMLUWmaTNI5//AINIhqXehluC7g57QBLVku5oqzJ72DzeCxOPXIfisydHi5K52skmzo@eKSEe1NCd0K4vjZGAQBTcNVgo0@9D8YComDSjnb4j8fymPpv4HhoM92EfoUTtsHUSfFSWpf5H5L7pjNmXUhEJdFxZ2wbbkdUjBh2H2IpT0GZw8JJxwVLtNd5scUEzHGucBtqEhMpk5JzqpKni9LJtnb1WEkXQi0yxtPT4yfLK09VnyHI2p3s7Gwwq@dgFDC8DgsEadY422XhfqWQWMvIKKahvNwnos8DiAg5mXdeua8I@X7sPKqWiBlbMMKxrTqMh1fVxJYNMII5CHysC7VFyo0wu93ztBB07O225X@h/4m8TH5AZzoSjDYT01ji8SSJTOT0JOFBhwcxBcXKPEUHF1V/ssuGgfYBoEyFsXYXtqaFdRIAYX44GVxeXNnf4OrTVEU0YIjjHpcYO6mU4TgKMWVhBF9UHDnXL@6Ji4J3c7gGMcrEkQOcT4DTNdNzKQFuaYnYs0CKEyJrwWMUVomU6arMzc2d/oGp729OIZe00dAzXty1bSbnjSGYIIINcvVZ3j4i6OtoFu5JqmeSloiqzgCuiXInd4QP4SjeRiNqiipHVrDeMc/eRpcS8mIQ2TarSOAKvGTBLxW@T0vi1ml6AIEYQ6tOkWIh58X2OTbIEJ3uQMU/By5k1y0b0dSeKOMCcbizjaotSLsRZBeacOwDi3KaYkY4U1zCi/FjjxMsy2kjmKF7ROBrQZsjxTjWcWZLTTLDVbSQBsJF13NAC/a/vbXlqu0b/7Lzb9qAob1b/in7HKZ7vxrek8S2tqfqOGQI7Wizb3MJm6le4KBGzFHXA2ARBCN@2ZEUMk6gBtfqOpr1M6pPU3D5LuALsGmgl3JyO6kmCQC98BjKnN@9xKA521@F3a3J4dVvSxCFV9LSQI677J7ZFk7mk1RiSkPI7QCxNg4gDtSTcPpcwvFigs@Yd6L2LYez6zmyeTrGsbKhIbd8pENnTPHsnZe5jiyXNFktrGMf7@IL59l7eOA/bA@2LFjPHN3jjwR/jjfz3M0f@vwVz1P4x3PFYc8fjNcge4Y44bDh7dHIa9sEMjjmf8BrcaHUuOjgfals/0YmiZwFggQcM4UNKH0tF9O0OcaJysz8sTq9HMBJaWoZjwB/q/BPd@SdrkLn8uB3@V@18/u/c@WXd@eU1rDUzRl6rdla49b9PjxOVMJd@MXN4oe5KMfeP9nRF93RlDavpjGH@/97T/P@jnj7VPX26hogJcuEg4evv52bRRKqHW/V6Ym7hOzpoVw557GdzpYu9V6uSoc1Du3sVXVagras/jP@qxn8V0oifkIYOdxGxbWi8l5ftqTjLi2bJpxwKTlbSE@mviYxu9VcvWMl@RC9QIqT5YGukNyqkkHvyMblt8hP9MZG@8eLzvTiLbNfJMnFxbm2gZUdYcpMpLpqvTpK5tBKvK9scA1ltHR3sLv4PIUMv@EV7oRHyGNrrsNs1K4m9BTuKo07pzljdAexDvedIsYomJyM71t7eMbvM3S3VOLDF1Lo4e5MgV224/6O9VA/6hpWVG0dGRBtf1ze7Kpjmmu2FvKG@S6HZXdY9/kNc@kxz6bM1daA3BneRKtAHfpoXk33a0vLyfWuA1PLxBxOw6FH5e2bV/wU)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/7rukm)

[Answer 90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132659) was for VB.NET RunR interpreter. This answer is for the JS interpreter.

VB.NET interpreter understands only Windows line endings, JS interpreter understands Windows and UNIX line endings.
This is used to distinguish them.

The code as JS interpreter sees it:

```
␍␊
S\\␊
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍␊
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF␊
```

The code as VB.NET interpreter sees it:

```
␍␊
S\\␊#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍␊
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF␊
```

`\` is doubled for Retina. `<` is used instead of `\` because it is golfier: `\5` breaks CoffeeScript, `\9` breaks Retina.
`F` is not needed for JS interpreter – it just falls off the edge. Cannot golf `2^2^2^` to `2^^^` because of Maze.

Objeck was moved because `S` must be the last. `->` breaks IE 3.01, so Objeck is placed after HTML code, [like Maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237266).

Answer (score 1):

## 360. [Raven](https://web.archive.org/web/20090401085433/http://aerosuidae.net/raven.html), 16038 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{'F*Pi^26qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#    CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 # a aa5k x##  k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz    "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem     / \     <!--      mxf          a5   >2.8.7.@_    ;    xAegguEayiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR                   ]++(--[                :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^   p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_    x-----x         ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S  11111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ### >>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O>"01",,@_  h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e           xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx r3o5o8ox xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2                                               
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcu c 11 xx   .-#351$#& xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
""C""Hata#8;s0::&&1Pr"93"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8"t."F _giogrl61op#astd[]!!92[]?42>805在ｕg=1*\0C0<?ML ma5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main(){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num();instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^);q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d(B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a)pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe @,,,"284_"># 01-:2/_;:@,,,"285"_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k-'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print 175#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65" )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"        <e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NYdiD4saPg@RFXoCpJigRAgG9SpFKpVFaqKrOUnVJWlYtkMkESJJECASZASmRKyuju2e11255ZT097ot32uNo969n2eiLGO7Gzbu/YMxH2fpxwzCf/gPRjY8Ox4f4HveecC4CgREqZ7XHExMZCInBxH@eee@655577Oujo3vBnP4vhxZ441nxgORM2MbwJ67nmqeHK7N6c3dVNL69lBQFj7bqD6ciwJ15FiDGVMUu3B1N9YLC@aU0MN808w2Adw3LOIFxjbHtqTz2jV4e3LGO2ccYO7K7ZAwhs4pwYtvnacCEsx9h9w7oYXUxY1xmNdLvnsbFr2hMKzTP2RIeX/rR7wvSON3H17sR0bAgqMPbMtvRRp6czij52DZ6oyABU94TSLIeUGHvsuJ4BOThdw/Mc9CyDp@6azqPdTz@6El/NsI90QGpsGbMr2asq@9w03N7VFBr77PjBg6u@WfaJ5NjswXWU1BzbnU6cg8lV@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBhaAmBPDKmVKmatBRahPY2J2l/KBgAemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2ZkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGPMzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7QkwB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/n2jMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPhobtMzOAkwHEscOxejkl1IwFz@u9HssAHwMeJwYzgWqEVoVls@DPHBeoBrECjHxgxNe8jMYM6gyqqO9UWD6TgfD90Aex1S3P8ZFZRg0DbWirVGcI94nrDFx9BNToGUTTzw6eMK/ruPAGP4zL29NNYLr6hG1vs/j@p/fjrB5Wi@x2hLCKauwcqiAWBLJT3ZoCh0RrwoH6ccPUAlZZfCNeYXEgi5ZhuRzLQbMtMS0PRFIzZXBA@9eyKvwKTCuxnAotKB9PYz59Vx@YlsGhDBBKERlfyzMN7pkcy6olHnPgWH0erUuZFVm2xApFVsyzItzLrKxBbgg6x9RyHn4F@AG0MqCiwi@b44AWfA98iry2x/r6yLTmPnQC32V5lRUBIuCrAmStBBDgmc3iLws/Qmv5isKeDIHaQ/0UwEuWeYLSyAgFElahAg9la0shiYgil2fvDTF7IB0QLV9iRci@AJTIAQpAWa0E2eczvCDe0LAsP9nQw2SEbTEDP8C8CHQoAfUzQMsMErMIP3gHeaeBYNNAimkgmDQQJpoG7ixmAfEKEFaAqiz49Brq3glkxPPRekR8kOgARkVqoxBTkUgAAWqLZaHOCiwHjJBFRshnGeAPuBQLDORYSWWlHCsVGdCznGFQNyrghVyigvxUAR8VgUH9q8AAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjikzUJaII2agzQ5cEPFqQX8QTrgDBWyVCFPTSsvmBBw0/JQ3nyWuFMrQO0WIQzopgGuGrCTBthqJQjHtCWgYQmZtxhPc0LoSAeoFWR34EMgRh7wIbgQF9xaMcvpp1vjod5Bac1TdvqYtIDNoIBkhKQZLB48c0hNQCUDYLAVAPoacEAWyJGFqs3mMPtLARow766j4g@kxOfY9FGYocAGYeWQKF7wZMIOxE0SpOOy5ARRZgFvQnfR1VGsYSM3SEgFcMyJzCAT6FsN5xR1AZI0S9l4JI06Lnb90HX0DNdlGBf0BS9Ncsubdjzj1RQ7pwVefRCEBsjLvm5aIQLUOPUJSVV4xj3Ib76Mdt91RtSCRyiXLMcZr@kDQAqeIaCHzpmxQH0hJPXx2IKuCPwN3hMCMmc6KTGk8URz5QhBIkzXHZoAkLICEW66Rpdo7xcdUmdB2C@jWGFa/U4WodyL9FFZNnZAfnuYxp5aVgU6D6PLsnWlZ5wq6MP7seX@C3EIejbon3wQHR0UEMScsAgh3dFk6jOPg5r1nNFy0bjQOgiLPjSxt7HO9DnUXh/klTHTR6AmMdRFbOghR8AxvAaxJkARxGIdsJ5jxychlDMXNAModFgS0j6QJhNzZIBK6UASrPEcIY0ikzDrzIGViVo5mXRIjskVQsnCVUJxj1zEgzcW6EN70y5SDfM2beIg6Hs8VJxcQ@9xP2HismZTh58LneTYV5tldGDEI0QtonVBD2sA9X11pksQseM3bA90NU9mJiq1wPkDpw/MdmZC2UFdgqQL2F0iApIg9JrJXVkgkiMDjU4sZrLueMzAH5QQYM8HmRL0685Lk72GQGsIell36rpzNhtDTZgjiDXpOv0@cO9rYzwEEGzUY915F5onVDJyj9BzSCJ1x8vFXLxtGhDHRk1v78kvsoEBZActoI8qP7L8ogDjMRWBSKHbXEOwdaAUFqE7nhNZAEyYou84Mvr3HMMjZnHck7DpY2aeMaCmAe2svxBGI9R4gEtt0tR6IHn85oXwMUNhZWEwK58LPjJsaDpd4Epo9FB9WKe7rA8jl4hegMqb3u0a44nPJw6JM9OOKFGHD1CJIl/JByZ7Q2HzLtu@wjUQNeSciIKASiWiPvZ1Ox1lrT88ApXBNhZ6PJcs1vxa9hDj9Eru4guMs4TBC3ENDmNqEqhRkpCYTlCUoHQ0u0OUhROUNqTEQGtzp9eLD37R7N0Rk/ph3oiNCmJHkJXQC/FYD0OCn3UdkDy2EFZ9yQOjLnncAlr3RisgOyGSVi/qKyu6DELxNqAjx3ZWQAVihnAxynII1QUx4xFKDd0KmZGai7dURyiwFyN27MigDx2PHRdaBhc6cxqeUZVFuMsf1STCviIJo/3lrhW6jDh2@BPsBSHB2IKxHDUxbKmgruogKUCI8VEHyDyH5xhBmFo9wfLxOyPRz5kJ@lLbNlDj1d05BwLFg@4ZMpoz03VBDJ5iJ8H7oKAzkYlPoU@A8RdKViQHtfurmcvI0XvTjjm7OrTpoqf80hNOdZf1cVTjgtIBjSgR73vxZJX8KWUkSFSc8UShpPwuQkSKJEOVJ/owUIJO4gEImqO53U2IS01MTDNxOumXxCQ4MCHX0djH@nhyFbuX4IdMMzqBdk1vVTaA7luS4C6hH2GCAYqMAboLegY0QlDdy@VeR2cXID1giD7bo9SoZNJTlXNhXobdC/PyCYG4RMsr8yw8t0sOKdKrYQkwOpWcOoklAr4jJSihCB6K4vet6EHaHg8jvYZ7Tm2a3GAJrook2Xmo7EMHkCBkTFA@zK45afvqyp07geKyUasBs4E2BWKzl4wOE4JZIBkkNUSWSRvxM5EnztEE20YiCeXFyJccG1CbgFNrdXY@GbrQ4uj9UoBIQFbBRk4OCOvX86fmybR3taJt9MRIIrY6UJrM7kSsCtD589ZQu4mq8SWqwlAijlRF5sX0BPoa85IvVqjoR3MND9Xfmo9KpIYTiIHPqytJxJP6fguG3pt3LV8l4C5o7FwadQD9E392IBREaV8nCBrttZbKgWBz4HDYk93jhzW/LfJApWPalSUPy@nqFnlvYnQxSPvo4N7T3ae/2F4BwzI7laseipkrFbCrnc6kgT1VcrJW2YzCWAC@374ZNiZcjiMKfjCTnFlEVZp3oXOZBeQ8fPrJVZKAJoTkoBzAjb8rKg2PA0qX0NG94ZVOmA1SKcgyTBLEZdIBC2CGDkQdw/UAnyfT16@x8q4iNfb9ETNrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8ooAFQZ0@7xEpLWihpo2ztwtXNGaAz0eoNV9FhlTpCMt8dPhg/2mNwPqTFRJFUbwJ6FK625OB561pzxBWxQHxB64uS8kLxFGfJlxXErjbXSLwom7ZGvgAAMc6ssMkaxQUzRsC7ntXy0a@UjfkAHonCFf1yqg@1H1fRCN4YBfXxSHvql6UAhadVei1sscKQ5e7rW4@bxRz5Wi31V3k2YsCpZlW6AcCvdGFoBNPQh95oUX6arWP/tGja4h7pETCUEAKMPMsJlNeniXg6EUyWdxT9mCE5liG/DlJPJGJSUWJB5OtctejwWck/v7MnCQySf5UkxAXct/dPdDuB5H9eUCayaBBA47FsWdy@7ho0vWAR2zHcgYO24I0XDsMMgS1aW0xdweOfa2GdPTEosZw3QXkL07c6GPoa8zXNHCkVNHhKl/B0W3vDKS0WsgikYhCBEqh@PJL/VQHci3KfXTw5T50Imo@kwndGbqABJE0RC50dSO@5MEkyEj28VlZwHAN5lprDwKkyCIIFtoXdGHC3UXwSk@SmLKyMv5KlD52rlH8pTO/wlrgw1kLHBGSHXz65NHBp/uPd79oTrR8fuk9lykXgHCQXwd0IXnI6YatdYs3TSwWgotB23CxeYEUmMIAJZiCn3ouCG4Zo8gcgTVcw1evEh87QzvuJa8W5gxDpZd2l7PQY2x8PKqfEAbaPQsHIy5fAsT@HPlnOJmMvYqiQCsfTjsyDFqVl13H0gcKpYOOwbIUFYcuB4c4r@GtSgHIeHODp@CTW6A6zGkGUbdGDgxeaCERRQNLcPA0a2WZgyGMhXG10XCTcsjBVBqlByMEGCsrYdlIANMb0NZ/BvUkctb@QNVKnK/VjJZTxCDaUvOHuBt9A4ZOCeitgBTJK6@sead5h81BSiOkq0BiTN6iSQ6PYV9gMVAkadYUx/kBcUha4Hwpygqi0aspzuaClFLymVxRLeQVGJbBMA10Vgnn3KSRPukOpYkjATzJ6dO8QYQL@15Xt/vylu8IkAW970MoarbxvNm0W6CgN@8QbriY15i3GmorWWXXk2z58ZNV4N6l4iHvBh7Au@QE1qQnWyPPevp1cdbTqXX1mDIZjf0@Rxqzx7ugSL12QF73jGjbwwRKNFDZWoqrYOQ3yooJIQuTCnhDSinQoKCnBdZTEC8JlF5UD4FzQG5FErDFbAYvB180j8gRHHQj35tO3KOZf9RrcLbUGwMRabK5i1Law/nBCfSOIeejlIbKRSHNzow4zqPrHp@thET@wmmQHsZqIQSalQ9npO1wqRiYgFLR8BwkB/AVTpsOF7OMOOgHToMMCSecfAANwqbVgwHIGUjMC7LLC8JzIp/lIp3YzpmN0DoGK0kdc8In@52piwuIZi9aNoie1XgcgEaFi8h1WmnsGF0@y8oTUylgEKizkTFycCoBtCsSBQYVQeerlDgW9HDGGppVRsJlGIAvsbt7IMW6Bp8vkkY4iAKW2mfxiavsSl8quvQauPkG3QoLH6liv9KPAwIsrxnTLIk/A0raiTOiSJ/TfAsG3gvUXWE8nwyhxMBhol5zxoZ9dczHR4SJZJXWduNxEPimnTiPb2xsxCvxejwNrh1wbaNrB10pcO2QSyIXxpPRRSnS5MLQBqVAv1b8shFAniVbyAMz1Bxem@OE3qhUsq203lD9p4bPJFQFUB5iS/gAOPFkrYbOZFKsn@GaDejvkbLvIe8cdV1z7JPgY1AI@LtPgywRAYb3qM27RhXHpjdTZFRzYdBooIqZcOPNRqbZap43e6nmZTyNqZNVvQbjQxBek8RIHrjOdAyKWyNXkUC2JRvZSqvaqcUz8a1EoiRZkJGeTH5YSqZ0TutE3ACeSjSbcSCpT51Gd@gSvFlaSyZDQgEefRNGGZaViMvnJci/k2wlU3FIm4ynQSzX4nGgSxeJ4FGhcUaAM9EDcwakhIYJXVx0TYEEJC1OYXP90hgP5240QjjrBlo2zqAvNgDgPgmU4lEp@Zqnjyp0SyP9QO/l8UC5xck71JfGcy7dBY5pU1nabhL0u6dSf@RMdOUzGQZNcqS7jG/EFUmCnpBCOCQq9mPTwyas24Yz9aIzjSsnQDF38D0eTkFYBnt@0sBV5lgwukOHxTfvAnQWrvdgV4JLVxJfAAsA9Loy/FCIolaCiyWgXdAuDRPkIu1voVkZlZDgoieYm88Xxq/kMLcqpWEZzMgc2I5rSEASSCHQlhTa6CTUmb8r5oBmvq6tS/ih1KXhwNs0QCI@sBydaMvFdWQ9aDyKpIfxOSR5avQEC@RHH8SjzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hB4CSoOSWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEtjhRgP56A6UzjPW0zSt0M33K0EYcgUQewiVhKNSG4a4QZCkQmDSr@R9Pi0UjNE/Pby/z@dOqLPF7hXn0dojpzcFvdIfNz017EGa7QM/mbYzMoEMQfrXJ9ZTx5nwUT68rJuZ4YNmczS1dJrzuTotc2O6rtNxLJoKuinpIv7U9XRL55NQQejuZ49B1392fFSTK5FIin46ujFvnIdcnS2n50F0zZHWW4PlIY8zpriZF7HfCrbSoZjxAwoYMPU30kEdBf5F9A@aFK6h@P4l9B/hJjrQlf1ZBHoNPf2IZYqIG@twF5Hvea5mLtF/7RgsjKdSPK44LrA9VzXyP530@0veWfI@kVA0WQvvHHnzDXZLY8QoSnkeCXfbLcWJAipQnHDT3dp4RYo3ph14criy@DjchDA0rGBp8SloLLh8Bp2@hXoVDFpQRecb4wzQsMe4SkKiG9feWBeUUO/afAY0trHEYwuxDWpA0LkpqNIImwrz576r1IRsx1@z9LhYdWDMT9Mq23W@yo1jKpcP5xQ@K7/ZBhDb9Wqwi2ldNMwpHg@jEVTCDVJQMWlh/1pRw20aHk22C5SkKngKDCdmWkZqzor7rYu44hEZ@kxsNmcfZrQvYFyCW9A27ygDo4oZrqNXNQiJ@zpsZ84k0PgwFp@47g5BzrDUbJmUUD9Tu@9YPYmvkgHDMD6@wgryNymEW@P8HZCG6Qa74mhbIk@K8jWyoe4a3CtVWr8eIbIFLwQEzeecXZykTy9YA7q8U9kbW@akxS7lidMeIkkmU9e@ulmP66Cuq889wd/jUmO7Tz/6rJFpcQjCSMeVrxKvxVmw5xMUZ1CUcHMuuHCnzsSckCZAOxFMLK8qA1IzWiQB9AEGz6DKwoz8EiHqF8bFoix9A0aqCQMx9@ajNDOSl3Lf0icTw@Y8x5cf15ObrxP52dQo@x1/0aHCMrQyA5qpiWGAYpUdHd/ff/pUBs71EvF9XMGpQHPUu0NQUNYVOqBktPAV9mEvzj7ENEkctgvQ1GD00fbTA1NXgelh/AG5o@wYGG4CPJO4@NIFb1rvooRcQ/MJhPutuhOiUQgsYSShTASsshL/ZzYfavl4VoDjU0RJIHfiTgVoayblqW2@kj3oaEhvhShxPliF/qK2mSAptqkmiXtcc4RLxzDCIqURStBoMOk1SDmILLJWq8r3AEBcHIC5A6SuKFJV0NbgmhpUfQ28QaUhCH7y2hv2vJGRyq3U5ipQtLnM39XLyx@BixCWQXvGymw3E9TerzVkjgNfC@SS@xkNp69saa@wTe4Q@ZwzRQ82TJHQof1Vy/uklndhQSNDUUJTMViQQCTE/D3XPs9SOEl@GPNgMvJIJNl5SHQNSc4uLoiGbFNjRENwqYxXxmUw@gTB9MiB0jzy91tHtQNqrf5GEmyzTUEMhlnLK7UYwlV45fSKdiqditF0XDs07ROH1ntCVzsjq3nUCMPUoxPresq@6Q3pthQ1xIHH1dZh5406fbqtiEDLHv6COnnQhLqvC4MSqStP6UFz6ytyXt5EspRtx@hP7QGtPqKbSa9uiSmVSxS53@mY66ICEXBfWPBcEQ2EFPKzJudkNdjAjVMx0B@B4OKjl0XRr@4/Ykt0h95hAqn853/@Rg/of712htBR4Mxj6GhD1401JfXXVpafFF/otrpi@QT51DJ1Igy5bgPZ1V0okm6FjtWgaRFekqD7H@GSgl/jwJt4A63xBjbjmPMVweC5OpNVi2o2iMzuurhX9mPxrGj5BwZ2PSICV4JMgxKR6OKVYMz4EkxkiI1i7Hakgk1TjJiZ1/twOpnyOyiut1aiOcbfTW3Tj5nJ6x3VgKGj3jGNG6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPbWwIu6i9LQGLIE64C8Ht9G5uvi8gK45gH42eK6LtujalDN63MYVnj31xlKHRuE9/kYNYXRDDq7F7@uimP6JqNCxnmqmRbd35EQfOjCKvxtCwb2mUoRo5hUyW3pnjjrI8P25LNxZABKn1k2lMtk1S8vj8fr0OJKk9OXy6tQzucvpsWqOQOH7WSU@i0YF9ne43lKr0F2ZI92StF7EuVaYr9qYcC1quKZJaYxTXNE5XVlzC@pjh9SdWrq7cN3A4gs8gmWEdTPSfrfxxOw6oA6MmVqUVS3oOiIdBonMYGvcIiPcTky3yPYHcxUZezAsxE5cCl2rRYDTneCW0TU89Q4CjW/VxA2xESaRnXWU6jpn@FurPgxhaMrvq3u01yuxegfhJFldS4d@fG13sDQ5iJOPtzDqmekZdFtN2JOViE661kr/5SYQTPtFp/FuY2vPtByPHdH9JgINXKACv69m6CgtTd2WaDI86r5BBgV7HBYVqlsDxyqUBooOt7W1PnX7KPf957tKuFBCqeotEipQfxxb9Z9r5fqJ4p7cVkF0CszF/a0R5w1d7Cox5a@9rC8dDAxw4W51yR5kSpRSVvhU35qMccnlTJ8Hz5@j61hH2qDrGM9JnQbtDhOUS@CYuFzF/nlyy92cW@/dhNI1sMXbChGp3BPLgM6K7teqlGkZ9T1TqJnMu4uovjU1psbKgcZh56WBZ5VvGGS8O1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1mt/ZPhOWGM/jW83ChPdMrvG7arMslAbg/Y9xqHzE3A8Qcf1FAN7Ol6q1aXRmf30ZpINx0GTdnpL2GHI@8qh0i2a0pJ@7hn0u3HExEd4uEGslstkMr4CE1lxWXq5aSSVDdO@NPl9KWPyWeS8iIurbG7EuToPIkt0C@JaEaStG9hT5HJZsU3bmMzx/o7StOM41vvUFAjVnomqGGiWtNX2phq7pu74h0jYYurCwwmPTn/dpAXvbfyxJdAHB803VXp0SeidalPCRc8RLkgtv948fRNZYLotFzzMjXNCfPOttV6X9GdDVLkkF29sdVxDdTqGpfPHrJC7CV5Zzt4Ib1lo@Iu1uLjLl3QXS/GxK0JpPAdimT0YpQyNkUGvN2j5eg/tDviPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vM9o3uughjE@SCjfelNeSIsjRxbBhfTXCfH45TLNxJ6vuuk8DBqt9KIh@M9IHBDWHcJCkXExa4m4YP6xbO1VMXFb6DpgvJFhYO1rMENKoTY@4Fz5UAH8@7UK/T0e3TbVcafxfnQN@hta/bwnq9i7WHztAeGkO@bzx8W9c4gB8n3HDJTagD1oMhbmUbj5e2uEfpaTmW9S70RNHIBaXj9FfitI@HX/Hk1nvBnesdCPAft07e6RMuO9CxttUMjSn0S54zccaGRG/rolo40cPv62RosEj9884g3TjOB4oEz58X/q1jy4HuTMZjerTH1tSjGyWV6MzybXpTn29NoU2RjjuQXzujjux7yv6@FVoCXy1iOuakO8RD45yzjYHT6Q7N25DuGPrENk@UYMqHv77T2BUpYzLpPnrLlgnkdecy8kstGn6Ej4N1le7PHvFuLXTcoK@smqGjY9nSWD/penw2FF2sghPCkdbID29X6Ph75dXUnCyARvYyhdO7fFkCHetw93dPrNWs6IzEQgz7uyrWcikp6aiQS0YGFB51XbbL@9wiTSyb5bd1CEVLSRhF9qW8D7n9vT80O2hG5m3Bf4m/ljYtrezk7OF04F0XmHy6vgcqGt7WT1vQXubIlDX0WbrtP9aRWbMUPOQIzzboXFPjxjWV/I2LKhRPtSTdMeHRhgdU3XTtHJpljj1@Z1J/7VKcv5cJxuJX1ws5bearB9N@xfSMPl8CQddtKuLIcXEnMuggUhdX0nEGHYU5V7y44LKdAQh1yWKLyEHcdWrLym1Cq6s/7DOlLz41BjrutX5kTnCz5gquIJZdtb3oVthfn@qe@fUplGwds6HFBr4M6UaP9uPbCniP9YHZfbhUESGSPoH9nZ78scT@6HW9Ls6Gpoc7mkLHDRNTyHKciZHr2jBuWBHz6rx9aKxi0YD4MciVsVfNrTvjOZ4Wm5Prpml1c0KzrP5z3dBx3SawG5E4m47GU89/rMaB9kxFZ6FHJ@TvnZkAXHoFopUNdWuyeqY6MuUKWpjfKS6c67TxL03LGbAvSxkGShsoYaicr2Cce9A9P8ENOa69ghMp73dc9sSJDsnlBXsFdWtkmWTa5uTm2ZzJBDfnBE8sDO858ISC8gjv8t33hSAdr6bIo9t1/cXR5Fv6d@C8I2fqdg10hvZGosMCP1djL9h9jCc6HLSXchYdpXUdC5oXOKyVTabr2NOJ5E7tG3uFwo29QoXNSoUIG7DE1/cfP0tGuYF2a9@mhRow@Jt61nzhWrth4AqTmTYoYuvl6HLsYCxxn9tJekpbhW9Js4vGnLokru87q8Y7T@bQgbzzgAmE/3R03@jisuGteX/qPHZsB3qjMQjK0VODn/lf2uixOiEme4Sn2oE@vVuzOSKwazohrm3oY6MD9WstXO/SF3HA9/WJvqYrorlBGv@Frlt5xbQ6hvuSJv0i7nVD2mWEHhozGlusZxjeBqVJt8tVYpyPW2ojSys23thxbH4naZuBh/r4ZqkCXQHd3n2hXMaN@EvzAivHZ8tFPTzlu0SMHjdKsa6srtFxLH6/YU@SbfI9AbprGp7yCG0ckF8hxyTQvrwbZUjxRhmyGBqBJnuqe7RIv3qosQCpzt5jC9BQd7sOroT5jht250QME9wipsO9/XzjQAcIPwOJpXenvgXG29CyRp0R3dYOGCK1@dTo4KmgDlnzmOiz65XJZ4Z8UwaRHV2hAYBAXGGjLrDEExiNJG/vtpbGUctUNcd0I0m9drmcNutItml0X@s4a@YQvRZz00vhUGblU3KumauONCOaRVZ0Oum@siUtb10DhcYypMnQhTG/Mrlpejsws7JiPWQ6MnCReXkVZq3q6nhDKqyzej09FK6uIfm2/kCWhHb/uH4o7a7VPBE8/B/e@1iBTrhdyAWmR0B03b6CD8hPXdt/vAsHPnG8Sd@cHQLeeApgnTjBYuUhCTx4y0DX1rpCQO3ZU4vPPgwi@65GPRqOSWTaVpIsEtcTQzLsU4kMwc2ul8jhh76UXTSJOjF6km8HAVcapEfB@a8wmv9csYAalY242VNVOGFnhZy//XMVcc8CyQD6ljORxh49lbH35ODR4bE89tSV/dPuEE9HXNPjlgwraKVMZErqpe5G1jv5drSe6U2Ue0eqtPfoQMYIa@jNVzQkeODK3NJj7bynb29UV/S1oyAMNSarFcSHx48fpRZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47OkrjSZOPj1YGR1M/gNbRd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfs@s2l1cJ30XJHTOkjHBoxGgRkfcrsstypXXWds9I7nY@Mz6DxRgnvvmH1hbSE/1U/NAbZCVl5LKGqorCwXcsnIzmwYbBtu@FxXnyfmGKVllx4Kf6zdjoKaQ1Zxs6u1h5tW/K9qMSzj70R4v0Rq5jq3TkwJWsZgiC5F9/6@iKmquo7OR3of6pXl11bWcoRV68OWc/oOS8mGP3iRQi9pAlwlmbfuIy9KIxDdCt5wet73BGdn7TaYmwCE3oWVDf7MsOe6LdFa1k3qRQVS46a2G6N8abzDglS4w@cULUCvXOMLt9SzRJecyVsyPnYjSfb27h3cluCpT8ubY3306TP2RPfQCMnNEaMYG@@A8UIzeinhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV7rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFrp2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1f1VV0@r/Vk9Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIeHDVO4wN6@@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@31EzQwFkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtHQRb1FBo/kytHoI2OG21H4bPCqQf3K/q1wQ99XTK7vTm4KK90Qlrshv2th6Mmycka9AWD@hjCWl8PgR451NnTkPd01vBX7j1cidFNByjcUpByRzq9LGZwEpYVF371excejC/5jJbceGxM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyR6jsfTr4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c2NVZm9Fh/vTqAJM3JyiAQgsZwSkcirgcvL5B2QOc17IHJ7Suye85kn95uGJiFJ55X70Uwx/en4/UYg2xEO/9XxflSxM9hzOyceeweHo1bqOkrxv64P261/zqdloUTg2hm9OHxbsBdh0eKFslxgcUXT5a88fDo5PAo4ucas9m6Qa80WzeGXBmyyPXT49xSttv156criLX@vBGoGyCPw@daPYgLu4@ProsEHL4NJyMrCPlYtxczpksV1nMmdNJwZeCT@Yy2Ua6s6SHfxbYqzO2u8F4a2EOHbJqQt6e022hZv91ex5XHxhe09gBqEJtwtYQD9Q0vGbPcMMCQkqxtqM7JQvlZQvdoPDTt2cqg0bo0tIs08dJb3Qx22ZHlnLFHoVWhdeJBWw1cPzVWUJYfHYWco2bHvbRvOIYfteYHXD05sA2fSNipVDK5/HWT6GldNM6b2ETjlJt0MhfiXlywDf80LASIwfla//wv2rCD0bmBB3gFAjGpbUI2tZqaL7Md/JxIBXTvJOWIXmQpLMirwTbP/aOtlYp6yTZqTKyIzD9cHBr@5cZrAS6a3YQyMelEZZsTCNkMDsYy@g4Du2A0nocBhJrPwJusRE0EVP2jw4DS5vmTgyf7R8e7x8@OGpnWpX@0OCiEbUNugQGDD7M9Ecrukw30BG7Kmo60W5AdfSMC5wG8oFwMSnalaLWloi0KJe5gms1z21YUOl2tSJeAnyTy3CgUuR28OOygxFQ//sH6Cj/oTOe1oYo4aJHyhDqrsMyqjMc69Hmbth9@9ds3FIrfRqrg15EwY9/6MDDiwHF6fo6ewW6/ghwf7B48evZ0nwUILpjmzOxNhrVynhun5hYfoJ76Jm03q7G4nyQOdVWrxR/EgTBxOc4qdB6eDEMDn0O0gDp4kt5PvcUSmwQfKBgPK0X5z99QLuMy7pxOQtx4gFQcsgWWJ0bZ2Nhgx8Ak7P7Tg8/2nzLEf/8@eSOJEAQ7xsO4f/bjHv@0QmAsJ/gulDuiDoqMjQjRA/nBKfXFQXqkOTXd8fqvQ9GnDOi4evgNhfAjMIJAn9gAvj0jO3dXbKAlySwR/5qVb6IuyIhYKDDHjpP0aG7O9dip6Zl4WB5x6KP1t2Vmx309ZPFQZrv46Sv8wJZO3/kA1Kf2hFtY8u2sxIDT5FDkpNkmIcu/CiJGIsa3N4DZOwboLsyzTegJJxX2EjgRJ8Ir3JiCJNXj15IEoCvkkrC/i0S8Zi7OU5qu8vbX/okyqDJwT8D9Hd89y9yDt1/x3/rg/lXufq4go103L7fAJYoQmoT0S8ARCemPtI988cvmBiwWhEMreIFcZeYIqumUqI7ReQ78LoE4XsBJND6DSgN2gxrzDVfw/Ay3lUCblBVFQZZCfVqmYwPGjO/hu2KbspAv5FQFkJROA4BkTH6Ah5M5wGSyAs1EODXHtRego21vbzMRB9VGrVDlNats2s@z4osQ0U2IK5wNEbkGgzSQZJECwup@Muh8UmoSk6L0iqtxFFw9B3olCsfeC99tnxAiSwCxOI0MtE4@w4/DTdx5YGO1g59Ti3xoZNMHJKnQJ5ErKQq@yYdPnQmwDzTSxaeEuMkH3MPKe0A0XujxTyaSaVPkR/l6y1qcVA6@aOK3NRllAAeVzVztTKN1K36OII4QREVcxb6N56w5adothfMmAzb94QpmtsH9y8pgDc/ycu9eN2yZuGqWEonF7h7ZDs4ePIDCsISmaFlFLSQXRcrlVhbJL5GfDRQHredcQHYgpkBkdA3zpTP2dvf2Dz4@fHJ0zXgjxYxfjQZyv76dakpyutEKHfFosZar5N4D5ejxvQdBRSyQLkSkMQh@vyTqTSVZTAoiyMUhk6tFW4Xh1dKtx/hzfgz9Kr5Z7SbUKNE1PNTMe@RLG72lB3Rc62rmWmkVtfL5m1BawFMioPf4WdtrqCaS55eN1na9acfi1zlhRUN4HpO3sBGAq@ltbSrI7NcLhwULP2Z6jF8086JtMbu6LYqbWbQNhkf9J87Jwnqa7xEJiJQ3yAZEpCArQdS1re@Q6@gLG38a/9gqNyoWNZkUQbiQuYniEVDHwXdbUYosLJT6xjmHMOq0zI4QmKriRjoDW4KhfU5uZiqRFPzvXPCME/6XXGeVmUy7uhJJlHYEK81usvcZwEsK0KBRu3syhYHVE2fM7Z7T6v19I3A9dUD83p/y0b7BPp6OIF6fHk8NWkkByS1BYqBkPESV61IgJXxzn7MUGlSF/Bpo9NMvuDzq5ROzpDw0Zj1zALI9kUyDRPtQVVssNAmKhSYToHZcpDpb1MKNTfEjPEEdJft72YWdLRDQG7ps2j1jloifxZOVFuSP/vGzz0/jSXEVL5F9Wt9ga@@qodoQ/aJ6syTRJ37rDKzArpIW5fJ1KQF@VwFzg2nBR5fKZXnoCfQRvRpq7kcT9xE4QY1I9Ef6mCWmNjc2JzN6TTQTdpqscEl1bsjSZqkUDajgQQEyo5R9cvH@O6Hbc5ZQasAE6OvZPXy8NsesocpyC9yUSZJt4sfQ9kDjQvOLSQHGwJCkQmBryEIwzACMeCOROYNDGgyHuPAgk30rgunbUDTh7CBNqNSsfodFPm63rDmK5XLFr9BlqVhmwH3XxaGsANhrci7Q64G6vh0aoBkMf2UhthDk1yVejPKNcUQe@gZsAJ1YxPhsYNeGAayFadju0MVfYt@GtgL6QaXy7PhBu5RURBYawhm4Zg8XRLj99HCI53/xBpqpshQ1XuUjuo8wGZocbHNLO2j57gE1GPGKSI1FyXD1@9QL3lTVG7neT@jXAsTMYQfgHxhsB@DQTGQwg7UibLWw/9nP8AvYYmJTVU/a7mkqns9U4aZW8yzPPtxsStJmI1O7u6nDKGryataEMbmylbt/agz7vYOB0hRFlmU5Rdk6P48/2HpiPtcKr2aXWbX06mSsFhryq1lLLNXSJy325MkXb9pvkuLsdP5KbCY0@hLz3uGFqOZwoB@rlNn5TiEbOynjB02ZrudP2AzGreyEvYbrpM/wn9yvexG3ju5O/zV9CCousliziZ@vFouiojTiLfin4f4LuPjAv1GX6/JO682bZEPXJ7M5M01z7PV68HOGoEFqySMG@d4BSU/xFdakJw2g6BrN@ot5BD0Pt7qGp0flu230IeuVs11jMJju63Nz@mDy@MvPg@sZXq@frpiQaKVSCUlqXPWutPV8jGkZ7c9@snGZPn/S3v6zb44UYwMfh/j4zuVjdB@p@Q83Nj68dy@XS2uaxt1Pvnzyi7u7u7n76fyTRn4nJ2U2tv/0TzY2NG1bUzZanqe24o2Tky9ELZMT5T/7Ubz95MnXPa@e/T@/8aau4q0It1NWBDkBV5ap4MR7CX4q6ljvesVex4DL1dic/tqxwP98g6n1neJ/@d7hq9gkVteUz114TmKvYoVSjDvBAW/Z4O00Vo9tY7TCZWyu1Go1cBb/y7@F9PWPAQ6GzLfhVs8HsArzWF2qUZKLWL0ADlXTIN//@xvfiGDIxUSN1LjgussacIm5oibutODaomtbQAODUkZRgnj2ZDgxHKaW7qh38MWEF3jYBlpqNybNGH4emB3eZexpI5VKteS2BJf8HOeIFFXVmqp6B6SB9OFWrSZtMW5BMZvN30Er0Ema0Ro40GEad9jn/xBXbJVn9ecG91SIFTbuvrhfr0OhsvXsVj1Fl9@SqFEVS6Lj3BVZmr2IwxCk0XrxiLccVhczJU1Mp9O8Oc2QVNJswUl48XssFvpgk2VX/ZaSQBTfN/b@8WL7eP35//bn3//z79Hf9@n3H9ACo90z@8oWRDqFJlGH626l0q3XxbornjfxvQ58lKmUKiWlfdlMbIEEaj1lauaji3g@Gz9iKP6hA2DNJKWGi7Kt@9njez228K5zn3rUzw/gkcmD@aUgxxLVyB1S7Vo86Fr9vapS47TeklAhqkkNtZBvSTxVgGW9zBp3oZpErVgWW3Utrx1C1akir7jhpsecGIwMCwEdfXzri7LVw5DFWz3qFasHyeqLOO8bL0C3LsQaDaVlUIcQ@LG7G5WNUqVQ0ZR26Hn9YtXrXoZhPPFip7Hw4tSJLQgaC1nzql9QFeELCziYvU880IwiEmwWXhHn1avNI7hZJ@@UnGsxaX4frg34o3@4wle8b5CP701Rrl8brKJuaVkl/2FhX2PvdwnQT7Bup9N53e2gGqB39K6uTvSpPtPn@qQz7cw6k@6UdfHb8Igvk6VYNq9uxu6sKTUx9ZvGBnvKpVCLpYKrmbr1eibLbd9JDgd/kuTMYkLsH@Cqq5rKtqB/ysANlDJywpgZ/1RVYLFzuFpvthpvtqCB1lPbJB1bdcnHEh5y@24rJV1eNsBdrfr/2/XQWaWLu6BwrctUavt5HVSP5/VGCkA@90HKEiOgcrve2qaQMDM/Nz94uwXKi5TabmzXnD36QRK4pHjOiRecuy0AvL2E7N27KRlcdwFAfRPaYzKV2pSkDewbG35fAZFb9VRQKsQhAdrC@fnP@YOBHjTZy@3L@mVj@/Jyexv@t@l@6T/B93L72j89FteaOIvwFoqWZkOpN5WmLyha8C4rdfSRlSY46vCEeI2sVmo10AGX3Ppv819OL@6hD6LckgFrIbbFtmJoDzAb2xJiL95@9b/gr/n2q99HfZHBn1ERYufYrJUtHG2W@aATbsx@bLPH/LLBjb/gFX3Q43EdPW1@s3FBSlFeyKzC5/wTaqmQlLEDbjv9NpoYkNkLiIqKG/RLTNRKBbGdUucai22LhSL1TL9w7YrH4//ohVYuxvn0DJ6Mf@F53uMIbgvsIHJVy6iSelHnxt/5dzp@YdX1j35h3SXELsrMqABVuh7j9BBiwD4xRZEk6Kfq2yPcO40rJBIORk9rX0jPdiWcPdEntP7V5TMDtYP9Wrlc54s7m0@osWzd34K7Cv/7G1AO1uxD3Ga/1h2B3tvsZ/NaE02Fx6TOK/x79Br/2HEX/56@wj92/Br/nk7wjz3u4N/xK/zb7eDf8Qj/7r3Cv8ev8e/ZAP@aX8tm1aq4eU6kSall9XJzJhKJqrGdevNrE3desQy7YfZa/ldwsrkyS8aaXzNm@C30Cvfsx3/63W9@M16rxaU4fVskpzouU5NVoD6UyItX78aFWI1tqptqxsp0M2pH7YDDZBmXZYaZodqD4UlbZRmDZeaZOcuMHLUHLgP@MuAyM32WGbCMnbEhIoSCa9LOTNDVh8cA/voAyIU/E7cCdtRMl0FGFqpq9FlCBA@ui3ZTaLA4E18YMMKUVTkjF8wWfsylIb540VS2Wlq5xGRkKrndeNGMt8SmiAa@tXKOdebGRvOFKGYLGZEzH/qwmOfBsLUaU5pNhZMJKEBUvLxst/c/vd9uK9j5NB87h4v/w8NR9PXG/9Gh8/jQGTnwf3h4CA3GqKfupkAs371bAzHtP3Zi9epOs0LCPhD4MWV7p1nPSugupECGa@iXes9rARGe9Y2mED9L4IjjDAcd1c/PqqdVcp8Fr@BoVxcRgmjc4T/hOoOOLRiEnMF1eoYOekPn2efN0MUdyudn4PU5g@FW@A/Duujrf4V/87@t/8fPWJIlGq1k4vxyO0FXEv@SyfPL80v/Xk8mEv5LYhv@0APeMcn5ZR2dFOkcXI1EspW8vOR@cE8ktznAOmSzXae0i3jQGcTCLClbfkv8131C1v7VjFcZCCEaUucz1I5iYpXpi900zeYsk0lWO8G3C3BtWL@gLQvJKn24brPTUFt/@iP6PsVOkiLlc9WqusX4i5bTqtVc8FYsVaul4GUzkShfv@qZHbUAo45cLpmsVuFlJwCbgVdI22BvUqzGmnBv3bnDMylpFxcBzGyukMqoGUwd5JSHbA1P7/oC9/zgkD7tAKImH8NvqnBRksjQh2Hw42NxsSLeuZPwP2q@s5u8c0crZy4uQp/xGLzUJa92u2e67Tb6Zy8uxLZIu1/KeXjPlC4u1Ew5pcaTjpv4FL9aB1klJJV9qNUp1zKIcS1XhGAfgfz2diFXrxdy4FMoxZO4kt5A9FuAb1yMV8XYOZVBLRW5BBSr6B3dFQRtGTsFdn4ZowpluXwyAYI0CZrfZQz/XJS5vLvJ55NAmUuRx1TLZR41yXKFRClV9v9qGzAWB9WG/6F@lk3ltopbd0HTxT9v5UADZXL13Kipl7Vzo4Jz6ZfVrv/9XzSPYNy5ky0DiUqZalNot@/vHu@22zVRFFE9ght6knQX0GqEG29QyfPlFqdIpXqXqlkt5RnUJ48jxaGHYCUguqJt5dUSEkkw@2j9BEgiqESjDbYhaPTEm1DmlNsATxjEQOY9uFiPddgALzbAKVFmMosuZjEeTvduN4zk8MsPDV8pLV6hjxFegt8Ks5xFoRN/8mh3b/84rW1LLKY92N1La0fP7sVUfM0v3ik4i@9P93fvHz6DBE8e7e8e7X908Nn@syfg77GzxRUIff@@eEZdK97P2OfCS/e1bhi6MTWM9tl0evaKvTTNtgmVaU2hUM7AZZ7RhrKM9UW5qvDrmp7@8qXujulib3/47bc//O/e/s533/7Ot9/@zvd/@tX3vw2/H8Pvu/z53X9TzuP9p1/9s999@9u/A57/AX5/BL@f/PSr3/gG/9H7H8PvP0X8/tj/ReLxnwCwfuWnX33vRz/96ld/AL9/6f9@cP33az9Z/fv@t9b/MN33fvfmON/9t/D7PQ4riPvd3@Z@@LwW/7d5vF/9wdt/8e/4/5/6f@j8nbf/4o/x5r/80x/86X96@81/r2mlP/3Xb7/1vbff@ubbb33n7bf@sfb2N/61monefvft9//gr/7w9/7qD/9H@v8x3X/vXf7f/uCf/sX/@hf/@1/8of/7Cfz@Hbh@8hf/HprK3/7BD/H/e3/wt3/0Q/z/n//V3/7Br//tr/xP5PhN7vh//uW/4fe//rX/@De/9Z2/@sk3/ubXf/I3v/kHf/V//Or/9Rv/8a//@9//63/yTfT8zZ/81R/9yl9@89t/@a1//pff/GrN/ds33r96B/@v/gF83h3Pd4HzLuV6X5@vfi58/j7UWOQCfALc/ctvf@OXgMH/BWNvv/1jPFgEvzX/P9ZUivNj/vb/AYd2vcwYkgEX/H797be/iyT6H4BE8B/S6zvhy1IIf/nO4gXI@lsrEv3yT7/65z@it5hRqdNaDfbdJa2U2oLxzVa57Pff/jIOJPmlZWghAD@n76CEWgr7Dsq2tz/8xtsf/eO3P/zNtz/8Fey8pVw5vZuW1FvWwCBi/h3iYcTCu8TDiF9g/imaWJNSX8Ab@8IP/OKLL4T2hYIn2O5egO8X5MUvxoPwhJsfFIShPx55Yxcs6vadGd@56fuGOTPWePGihaus4Ie5p0j32ApUo3yWzVLBPDWbBfPVGGm2xaeuGZ/OnVHwTMDb4n/hnAkstZjhxi/uhfO8lBOP5mfBnUIesknNZpGJctJ7CEPuQ6vDlG@uzLAEs1lqBoNgcEAOKQi6B@p4rZbChDWOD7xy1OolRqikUjUoN6bmadLtEoKY3SMokLKWesraW7UZT5hCePWAHCkBvZ6KqiamSrX7kGFtdp8hLAROYF@8qNVLtVkdwb3h9EjNUvcIJwRWS83qb@C9RjAhnRC7/wZQKdVSqXoJM8RC8upJt3kl5alwVPYUS/l1AE/c5L9zl7EPRbUktrnCiATjsfGeWsTGiBAdwpupLb849B846bdFBN@grPxcGA/fId10h6urGAHgSpIsywx@uOy@w@5C8IyDSlG28EhxCCniCOKA0IPh/FBKSFH9pugF8o/Vtt77QmBYmM3NTSFWF7PioUykUxTmnlToxANuAsThRYWJhbKI3gYd/whwgfRVyn8zjstpccYBsw9T/Hf37hb7EIpJz4WfwKRU1sk5MQ5lO5USNYBfd1LCcxiWCMCnBOhCkGc1Wr5LCek0Y3IthmHs8PDQR4I8nteEFLC5llXxHReRptNpDFLIclpOp/2nTE/ykH2HTKH@U95E4tJnnZmm5aoweqoy9GLRoY4KQ2D0fPPmDdQK7aqqHMDgk/kbrLRciQLBgxvysKx5cExIy5UFPjJnaiHHWIKmWOFKsqTAEmwrKfC9@ByJ4ErEtVIpTvGA@nJiK9hvV1CJHXB6NVZHRIOLDwlL@WQQuHfI9g4fP97/9HjcajHBoM9UG@2x63QNz0tg2O6n9/k5DK1cSMYaDQR9XNFQwAj7lQwJ44P7Tw@OKowX2q@CBCFWpdVUv5hlVYiNx59vx/z9RiJ@ac0Rj/BeWZQtoZWzkDRWF2JdA0cWuExepX0mVeGxN7jnzGBMnxbFtFrAkV2SJpWZ8IvOlKEdUG40BNoUns6Qt7eJAkL9XKIFC3RCbRWEet3fqcdUoX60fwwJjg@ZqmVkof4Fm8mYoXQp1K2aZdiDyXATt7yJzYwYKdNmI5PGPy2bhbuaK6TVfLG1sWGdS5hnk6rtHPcuXsLruYTF@AAuJnwgsA/ACy7IAzckMn836MFh1d@Shxa3EnxfnqjmoZklBZzH5uCEcfSqAncvL/8IsY0vv5yweh3G19LBAyEG0mLIgl1pktmThzJVc2/qGhQ6YKxnfmbiJ/TknumNLX0OTQeoEbu8vOwDpIMHTKtr9MpT9PB@2SWfDrgvZ7oQsyuV2hs1VxS0k0rlTVbTBPAQthTc9rYBDEC7B7YU/lf1IJNstqSApFJFER7ZbFbAuWNBqBgCoy0ibzK1msR5MJtTaYeIgF9l0Gc1Lbz8uLMPF3GzGR4XQyCADSYuywRhRR7mvxUEegOi4Z44@gZw1W@cmTt3sjiJkc1lwtkKKjG7hLrZzOaySHHh/7/w2BVfzdke17MZdVsZg1MHZ25b0cHZAWd@W@mA0wRneVsxwTmtZ9XMtjKtC0zY5jY3GZr0qIkTY4YmfrmfWPcMqy/jiaKaSBlo4rZvw7oeJKz3aj2nSx/wrvZkEz@kjgdweYJcTqw6NlqDq6FdCDqyzBLJc2FQO6NjwoJRG8hoYMS1dUvoyR2nN5e9ydzCszmW49bioA7Gg4AFdAP0EJz72slmc5UGa8ljZ7wjaPliqqFmoAPBn1pKa@kNY6dYrPTkrmXo7k6@ki@le3jsx1/i2slnKgP5i8ePHk4m46cGnQXayZUhAZrkQuM5O6VKPt9qNEQx1aBsWvj5YS6epI0NaNOG3pPgiQtgnqSVWpC4Z7q1Wjy@k1U1Sa1kM6VLYUE4pDmWsC5g0hSWLI10P/clQMV2bBA2lbSeNs@JCpV@v3@5dZ5avAj6ucTfgD6Xkp7unIevVSkSr8KmaclcBIKP3gdyn/trexVRy5fEaqO6eC8WxGrrUrg7MnqmjkeAmpnz66kKIJQ51Bhk1GTCZcV1nEmlY/Qd11hEzKqFICJH6HqEnHgZZtfMYI7n17MrRCLNzq9DyeXFyzBVgJZweQl058QGsvsGVeu0VbahlnOtfRBBwD7bga1VjBZ7/lyIbT39LFuvQ1Wf54paLp/La9lCIV/UoL8p5wr5EjS2TCGT1zSAkiuXysVL4GtFeROjT6mxvfOA3ytkTD6hV7g1xEaLJd98alrnpazE8Ugkq5eXsTdC7MOnn2nQQa69EtDpfqZJ9Vo2XwZXFl1aFhBmgqZJWlbKqpKaxf9bHBr@v3t8Df41vEOqrCYco4mUT6HbhK7eZo/Q1MLEYccOfmxnwO4Z3TUx9oY67WPecx3P@3vEuafbJzzovsntkoZBD3X84pg3MifDNTGejUdoXcVw/8Eg7I86gCCKQx7hHtxcy3FWRSiyZ0/WlPJxaAkciMFNgUP0pwcfPTyOPI/3d/ceCgV27/DT@1ceeT9Snj3af3AcvhZ5aJA0H4L4xf1Hj66@@o/c4bOn/anj4k94cPgst7iFXnhMVsjBtRwp9CYg/g1fSbEEjQIGYvli4FAFPFxxBwbHd3xnvrBwZtD5OT8DbHrhZn9@HLwiHAcHg3WGkrZjsC43ooOjdTJw5@vyarEsCGNmO2esmGE9x7J0/Hx6fwM8hzoecjRQobUs5ETM@sxxrd6Z2TM2hMd4nrKs4qeqEQnhIQAZTbtkHAGUGTSX2sMPm@OyVMeaGmw6Zms94YFe6HTNwRD64DMniCB0dJ3B730vSG9Er8nNHhOeB/ldC7GuRxdigijuieJDfaLHSlUvU6ncuaM@ccVyVhxDf6x7A2N/BizLnkET0t15uiROZPEBaw9wVcMqqM44psMYpAEae1lrtHZyWr2Uyf/1b/347/7k1wc1dauZ2cts7zx@BCObfAVEG2ixjBRVX5mVaVijlUv5UjmrldKlcimXVwv5fFrV0jAiLJZhUJBRS2qhlC@r6VKuDFpIrgyh@XLRV4WVQPdVtioA1u7ip5O3aWQkD2EIxJch2euEnmQxPXyfMtGANKKAg9AJHRjfMmvQgTI1w7JFBhB11mWxBw/2Mg8eiOI9fMFtHHsZUezhS76UyRTviaJBIXsl1KhEh6cpoRE6ccJfMpl7QOUpB4D220VxiC/7BZxOE0UTX/Z2HzzAfPr4omF6iHbCQ/iLFbwUIZqNL6ChE4BXITSItsvzyRGi@/iCWWLIAx6yB2Gi@FGADoY85dE4gIdBSXd3RfGAv@zuYsgeFTvPEf0EX3bpEkUXXoD1RXEAjoELjU4UO@DEBiCKXXB15zr44Weq0cS3PdFFcc7JgwQSxRnF1rsnotgO/DGbz3xs8kjdCr2ovNR36aWMf6KoBUhjtGz4khXFXPiSg7I9fPiZPpz0jAG/5i5/dqGkDx9mdXM23X/Q@eijzmDQcee7@x89xaC9vYegjcynbmfQ8RN22nA5kGrvoaafjOZXLyj1Qbtd0a2VQZ@02zndvhLUnrcNxBBSvQLM/GuAGY3aexC097B9V1@1jEwA29j2R/Ds4HVvBM97eocHBRcF0XPW6YhVZH9FaSYEHC/gAjA2xxOQpXZ6pHddp4rvsxrLpFFlmTcKmVaVAtgI9P5M9RLD@wm86zj3kzyfN2a1TKs2qxU1vg@pnxCbMy1viumN0Y5azlc29B1Vy6VmFbRZ4fTjLC6pOyyh3tl6zRKfJnc0GAOIzZ0dSWyorR1NLVUKxedbU1FMVvC@ky1WIGImnmEMb8lGsbVTzEeSFIspXdEqxSKoYkCUCfToHZyTaScSZ4Z@kkwiujhDAEWgsrI5ldOs9hOz9KzG8WLzZHVWU6vctC3LXIPVQzvq0@7EcTnEAYCb7WQquAKfENVySYT8FSWRTIZCD8brwmLj5@dfPz45Pv6CVL66P3fxhH/4veq/fvRwTz44DN7QArr8ADVRx5X3UGothXCVNPA6hjGI/BA6URjPBX54NtB1LHmfds6BOhsEBDZ9ZN8aqXz8cAnO0dA54zmjaYUqmbSzuwZDA/Fmj@m1Orj0HksQVkxPnlH33a7Xa@3aiKwPQBGDVJ8wsp6@AHPgcdxDgw@U/BzPy/kB7VrmstqpzWIzgNOuMUl9MXJ6L7RUt9pDu/D3avcwcbUNz07VqBmu67gijKbFan/Hrk1tT@8bTwwXTZkcHG6CMoGH6BJ9ZiQ3WXMfY@/hSOVSqrvMXmD26XSU0KV6J7nsFXlF0iS@HhT5nE514g6Ny2q/xhLPk9VX8OpuskRPvpfcyVV7iXusnQSfzIv@iz7TWCFXpVFGAiFBMyLaYJn1ZK3@Ceg/HPBJpQKI@HV8AjAxJwBr9ihAT47Ny2q3ZrGExGYsSeTJVQe1Bqa@wNu2JIotSWpctIS6JH0u1KGlVucxveZNO/QxEZbpqFqmUJ2Bn1rMVYdQsfrzWdWtjaeuUbXg1Z/I44dX9SqQE6gGYF5fJN7@0jeS21K@xv2qBOrCApWjLbdrs6qN5gmBJWrZGgSkGrlMGkbvcCumobfXCmm1kM6mc2mpiL7Q1afzafCE0Q3oFgkrITImpjOzjKymVUNNJzIvzN6LZPokAUoLkYwl0xNn356OGPhAJSFX0is8dZZMaVsWjLp6DtO3JWJTkBVVLBjQfMjGZnqIoJ4aukUpkkmJZbcS1mYC42weT8f7jValsj8bfx2CEtKrnUKqmEm9TiariY1kzTNeCfWqUEe5QqUebwDP@nOczJuOGlDH4FKLWqXR6GARi5l0NpOF0pnti8G2WBdb6cxGQYUqumQkMBiXGNFpP9R1Fn7jNmrdlgFVp5a1qiDTHFy2pEllJb@Vz/B5QJ5SGPuCDSnJEk0xOKidiMeLWjyejFdxBWJD9KecQZqRJIuDWI3fUXdEUMPEiljWMMJCKNJZ3EyAHShilwJOfLAcDGrPhcvzy@268DXhCE9YbmvP8a/4/PHuIf59DbzK8Fp6/vjZ4bPDBwJTaJOn3I5VN6pytV2FF0mu3xViFcZAhjZ9K1LKBmPvu300tV1/zp9NPC0AcAUyOdxgLdrWZZg4YmOfoYWCHRaHMujuqKFp2VZDK0KvB3I0iKppahXXZ2J4HkGuQ2V454DfdqqOh/s@YfO5npKCYf4dxgapTYHIE7s6B7Bb2x083Q12pu3urZ4p2JwpODndBF0dd7LFzuOx@CX8CbG7dNRQ40cNWSw8bIhrqv5ySDZXYMlysFrxtfjdWDwex2WBCvPexKjegsNbn7zQgGVithN4wGgJZ7KgM8vnce48prwYe19qpezjg0P7vvvAYPwsVynXFusxllElPBJVrfi@ebG9caICx2TF7Ek6xu7GaGO9WC5posY9qjF2IsXVSjoNldzcuNhwcFWEhXv13tgff52xcTybizPWrMVmtZy/CVyt1yV1W0PTbEVWAdnfVwtS5qLOebxOAQUNQt7@0g9ys@0SvGsZFd41LZ/S6nV1S2PJ2PjtV7@PVnbO9z/bfcTiOJf@d3/yI634d3/yr2i7WfyS5te1bDEGMdGpFoqx8/Px@fklXDwsH2vFOFK5YhLcfK1HjdUVVcvatl1lFUXXt4qpnHbXrip@XLWoJmOeFPNXrYr5mHfhB2mZEgQFy0rkJRawBmL7T828pt7d3oHi7GRzWnUD6l8Nj5qy8G/b8MpQu6XHLy4Yg5duvTcYmBq5FIVV3khs@420zd7gks4baYO9qNVxa4CKB1SDJY8tPLCHy37xekrZijMYGrF647J62UrRmgkMIZ8bxpbdvMKwzQ08sbHstWXDn7Hl0R8mCjw8eA3ejK2XnpjYSipKrxeacts2WL4OXLGlAG5bwboH/5OkZvLtL/2GphX@7k9@7aJ90f5Cg8FkuVxQtdjPfrY9taee0av/DBLeYD4lGBDSohHaOUFHOJBk3Hqq6acKHXIXxrBTG5VmHj8YVuJAkoHCYQ5so0fDSuEUlSSqyDa34NdLULQttK6QJqWbLGYlq4IQKqekVLuDbppgsC20qtloJYVz4QMMgp6YgWJeFT5YgAKPEfS9TrftWVN3TOdbEpRObaXZHUgCOXyAxhE3yCqEL8YlkGfK1vWkHGWPqEYKFRsZnoemFqEHEj6AJL7pYWvOxjoaMMGYpg39hoxRCE8K6DUg7xbkbfEEbfJNUOl5hDTj2PFENijewgegSRAVTFAwmLkNEaoghT4AAkAZEj5gs8W2WTbJzs1Uqrqw43iJe/LR0qQeGE8QMBlC66GxjiBxFeOBFyj8@LFL5Au/hkG3i3gGQDgMvoRfgyEDJqc31NjIusk7gwJYZEksQUVjd@4ssKrVzF6SUYkQ/ok5xgkvqgd7Na4ALBhufdiriGmGFjKrgW/IdkDxFKELXCdx05jVSFIm4uulIMD/OzMtcuSVqqKAKhbAry/eKrpAMkiMZOd12GXbNaZqxSQLke8C7l1Cis6wh2PI5uxDWfsiCLwEDH8WCz4lAyLqODqJ6PPtVesZDLTsKX7HA22ocWHgW73gVtJQ1B1MgtRhKiiKaVHsvunC6Ib2FgQGGhNZNYnJFgYtCQ/aNa/lGG5ezyfxQakwNoOnjoYG/Xw2yEBS14EK9caOTZYJyXISnhwAjgAZ5Rt142hP7TP87pNfN5Q4ipFHBt2Q8xFjsrRIH8ymtLi433FhEBzQJs2Mgcy6ox7TyixBjEbG5@wQXJISEcIdUJWRxh3LGAFKR4ZBx828iqIMQH2adsgC32MT@Gr4wIT@xvYU/9vkypl5YirH@N0KyenjqTRuzySGGhc2P76PwLd2ZznOCbPME4PPDSeWrMF4DAYLoO@mgbKLHxC2ghtUtGwaZyvUNI8FvyI8itxZSkfSbiTmyevPrLqRaGONXlDnY7r43fFT3Y7Ql64LwR8fe3MvsCdFVpHgXQ5FruFbkqnF0UZEaCJJ8C1j1cgok4xrDuOEGBMDi1LoFMauccpwpCtgHwNCsxvYZsFWDKX9gDoAanvQstDQ5MStoEUhwMTtJbrQ9HwBb7MPWVYTMCI39@Wb5gIYWPW1ZegQBkmxHN6kBxUj00Q7yhVonaMehKEtC5/9MH3A3egmI6AL9mYbPjjsdCivGuPNInjJR16wdSA/U9E3ILAAGK7AZCMhpgBsSkyKHHSY/mpyzu0CyZIKuw4pzRCCT2qAQqqCjiKHPhO/@ECTAAH3dI9b8ffNUJ6dnclkG3XqmrLh4UeLPMfWLWU8MEGBdpSJMRr7n4c18bPgPtyFS@LfKpPHw/HODFXXWvnOnD8Foe/V/G0@iXjfi2PneIrf5BmMyI4aGjDziKEemPQ9r27C33XE@U9rpc8D/qsg/0ml@CUCYQzBzNLzdDcNwNKd7km6f9ar@gGn1CABONSiEXiixWI3eBl5gcsc98MYzgTlaBjUsU5o5RYgiXxad5E1L2EQcx68@u9jcwaJbOOM7bquPk9QeBJjIwMn5qT2sDl0@xQCTuhm2Dk3n2vOGvPWUvJZmBw6tXDfgotG0oTzm4FyW8oYPuPhMwif8fDZItMg28asxVUy9LrE4iDXo23NICaCmQdxLrnd4UUIQQbtm6kcBMacL/ldwq9bo9QBvfkb1GMtYAzgiTEQ3EgojefNRrNle8bZViulDIDZRSIE1DiAbrSIpme90I3Ut06tseMtedloUhV6JR9v9OoOfW7gvIJlDCuIGIPTy0QrmIORv8GCKwR@gQEC6mEQiKrB7iRhJquh7W4KBMZpiAsac8QaPjIt0r78IN8P1CVOek7YKKBWBBD6h0UCNCGEBS2Hf6IukA6fuw7ECeJK9FWtEVpji7fiQMkrTYXLmipVUgQrSQrQBLKjulq7WpQgHKqicSUoUsxLv/6j6G@8N/p9aBersSeG5R1GVYg2FdzTCCqE31yIqqxei9QrYKBs6ZbhQs@1z/VTv7eGbLaUYJjB88EieGfmpDtMRCq/m@T1QycnRVushKwwr9WgiPMab5a8XQQk5QQPk3l@snnACH56LkAARmZlMsNPNosmm9VqXHCw2ZpkZxEkZ4TkjCfhsWdrkGz5yWD0dBB0L1g9LdBOcdOlCPBU3o2CGjQWmaefGrgM/hItReJSgp/nQuYQF/g8hCo28lm3tTL3RgTpiNC6AgAZ8RqAHv/abUW4KvBUKXwLZRQnZSCj@JvPBlxWAIORCK5ya8qJkMloDAwKv5iifgDarphqCKJKk8L4l@E/MR14Bj/1umdmOaa67JlJX/n7B/FsIWUjDTSifaiZHApkHMk8s30zpFGdI4Yfhh86oNV1zhyWWKFsg78y9ZMqHcvpKCMdt7PgNzC5rzyeJ4PxAy6osLtjZ6JPnFyuwgdNJrHdqvz5mMEc2A5@OidiUR10vZ5jeHZ8ApXadQa26RlphsYuTwx/2GH4n3gQonqy73Q8QfA3VvFhLILmfIWqbruNX@VutxO4XzFZCTdf0/ZFZM94XMDxL7gi6UE8@UAPxwmn89LoTpK3w8TPA/jJjs3uSeJw7AfiLOkuAxnWBf0fQoegwTDPWYwcyfQ4qtKdSYK@lzF0Rs4AtL6pJwuY@gr4gwVsREgfjwmXNNNxSFuJfCSCWkmim9aTftJP3jsp@0RL6MkwvbYMYIkYaeZepTFS1l2RXXttdjxZkN/R@@N7FMX36GZ8aRR@FWc@NK/xwPfLOptYQICICzSyt6OBRQe51buGzhIqoTfqVTzBO6PYo@1iPcR0F6Lu@tHlPvBHOnzz4C1E/LN19L@5AoPk@@9afTo0e3Y0B3kzwp2XCframResjCYg@kESZc/17ELWvv@OeUFc/NDkA1QhQI0lwWWj1WRomGMYdnvhdHEA@Baexx1a1/ietm3VeOAKnNzTNDvR1lfR/XbPsPS50Uv4MdMRuEGJn8KAjeTVuxUcBR0JPYeP9RLQdyXDUOjGkeg8UmUNy@jp02RyPVvxKGbIPTRTThgerKcfhl8TzTjFV@Oz1TAOiMdjOB17auL053g@nnPD/Bb/1JUvR3n/w2sSrT/cThCgA@891fQi2@RN4vNpIizSO/QIYVx5uchoNzuAiEaVrtfh@5Ho9pJC5UYS1YJaFpY/SbO6xs2bajzCFQFP8lWmd2PJ25junXkuwmoc2EKE7b1fF3INMm7m6HYTUYjc58Yac@xrMgH9aJ7OXtOrtFcI1DAlSbqJScNt0i@SAo6MD@CJE06fwRMBDoxJmzNUUDac0/K/HskoZKSPI1qL7wNKOkCJUJGT3EcjEksI3BD9/DLMs7s2z@61PLtLeYYtYDnLSCShu5SlXwtYPTdVgWX0J2ukMwbh2BkeN4ltuGxHd3G24jxuxitmmsVP4xUQyHEjXtlPgFCO9@KV@@Tw4pUjcpzEK5@AY9G24hfxStAsMIILr@S4i/6@CMf3bryyl0heChP9xPCCfOV4JaxTiLPDX4kiQAosN2iNuMRmO34xJ64BHRsplWmGHOOlcfhE8zBp@mXgn39kij4/g4E4x7lFkVmKqUudRqTH4PlAtxF83mBFS674vfn@4QPaDBVGwWxSMMaLpiHwoIbH4svCiCOGobSiAU9AEOVmZTVGLNKTvSM6fu7AoVTJy/kT9WTSB3oJCm9A5NYiE/qymJ8@qK9lELwC3w1PTLwOz2voBNkRRrgmm1yBFhL1RfyGQmFdL@Pi1360hmiuezkSYCsFUXgtEdiITAcdjhbnMLOxM15mEgrFTfdmNA1NyvFGidx7JRlJBb9lrgkmb79kKBiijT95U3Ei6RC1JRGEgY1Mi7eysF8gWYxBC1kX0VR54wMUIjIHWrjRPaGvtt33nRSPi5s09RXruqEgLc@SJNeymITEMlqzmuoTnns4eN1HG1fvN3wNUs5wriWBACIpw1y4fHX@3@6@dauNZEn3N3qKtIQblSmVJGwwRghbgLC1NwYPF7t9AKsLqQRq69YqcZEvvWbmx3mBM//nEc6rzDvMr/MU@8QXkVmVJQlsd@9z9qzptdqUqjIjIyMjIyMz4/ID@ntf9HejUBsiTDQwS7GevZROq9f3rrITmHfiZqcHEB9dte3MVI6iFmKS0@7A0szv47UpFR8mH6LkS6MR9Alt35At2hN8g26TewuBBS1heJ18@XGJXn5cuptQ0xpJ59ozSouHljQc6XiEady1@3GVjs8aYnzh822/88MDPEwOsD14gMcdGE6QXGb58KrHVi7x3CaxLW8gUotrSgQ5X5dGwxy/JHHPV7fRtS292K8fbO/v7b6nRffp06eOXqPHMX6YtThrjdZxgcyW1dF6MGPbsuQitRIuu3EcH172h6MHp730lCwRYU3KgE@tGPbTc9zRssyS5xNzl@pJWYuiGtbHeBr4CakEVcfHkt3WdB0RQYJR9pGvgRj1lujt8m7N4SRC9XrP7wb1Oi9fJvOtXsUwNOZG3Plb5kH@Khxy9mnJgHWTSnFYCbW9r969qhypo1dVtXO89Vf1fv9YvavsHSGiwJvjzd3alqL/q3uHVZVK2FEiWyA2lETX7aARIAWsWioUniiGvNUfjEXuZLcceX/od9WrfiPANdV66HdfXMoPrxeMNqRWlbajY5xhtjk7ZLc9gr0FpzOkbSyUmyY7CsIVQFHZc9rTdrHn7fab7Vabyqaw9x20g9D4lqlOm0aQ5K1xr3ZFSULmQjYd4oyksMC6oeo@lcfdDYHxxf4KJEYJSXXY9JQmXPTfD1PwqHrw@lAhOMXW/t527ai2v3eodvYP6Oeb97W9l0TP2uHRQW3zGJ@44Ov97dpObavCLwSBgqcQNeLXq3B0LwoeijNVGh9x8@0NaPijX8lTb2jw6sZnl8lQLVz1IH3afqf9KWgulFJXIdQXuGnyVYHKzlcOXr6lNV8Fv@GG01wFs/1B@jjkbJrzBbXOrdFk2aD5VtLTlZa9XNHh@4juWCGhTlDiaBJZfnaVAc5GPM12oNJbsFHB2bcEneC5bEBTQw8INkAZg5Wy4kRYCwvuOoPcoNYanT4ihEprYkSof6DqC2NqUkoxxbStDIDC2aHWw3lQsRS9IL6nF0u62dFQCqjH0QspoJ7IC6iiNdiOqGVd4mq0fwXxrFbkxa/dwQ5fC6un0YtNn3exqxonGTceUl9FiQQRgqPD6c7klIdTsnJabK4ScnmkAut0ZGIEkoSSZKJcJbJtG5VMk7Bp4apBm71Jbmd8JW6AnZDfGoUqW3Y8dQTjoKDXlkRzFx2/JyZQsekO855aRbSjsvbIbkcJ2th9ZNBnBkRyyCQeUb1trRUG31uPam5OtehrG0lOkmpM0L6FwOYUAn8EDAHKJXY6DV6p2IsVYPotzcrZsE8ciXPb3@3yxM7Nq0aQqKCttrK/tj99cjSR3cQ@ydgpMnY0RJ@CIamVfJXZ6g9pjrNY5ZRWkIKNy/5g1JYxzCZ7wDdOvMxRaSxs1Nov5Y1Ea6DDZIu9fs9q9Jy4@I5Wz4kpv6dV5ni5O4/EV5zrmDifFmGxuwM6/nn/OrDuzlxcIt0EOH4hRZjvynH4OR4xJqJ/pmLZ8btCitTV8sb25mnu919c5EkVsSBpio3RIf4nxkRbND34no8NFofQu/RMM/ntwqtz1NY2eFpaYpYbYLQPvGzTvu5FvRR9E3Pj6fdwsJl8zy@/fClLrRwkk85tHV5mY@nmqhPTpMt1zpQ2AbFkJyFLsj5r3rgMM5LXL@BUg1FA@J4e5Aj27RPZ47QIMb07v2qRZNFJfPVwR/AdtcEWFXEGdDjL2OOR/5DdLC9uOPnYoERZ5MwaEe0ayEXHscxSeL2aArd9PziS398PbvVe7GR5@CFo2/dC@yHccot3w5JlyYL1/WB/vwesLG5/CCz13b0bsCyS09AiTo@Y053PRNa097f4y9TY8dwjMFh7cYISAbVau@rxFbWJt52VCo4NJlaIDo@2qwcHKi37E6pLcg9bhqYWg4D9QL2JrW3bPRZ2XqQ0RZvlSHkybxIWbZH70j2TeSbx7hAVWgdxNT0iYRFH9W61b0Xq6ZWFVQi2vmeBaCiXxO6zkUHhiQb8lfaAhGw8aFYHUzO7mZHFpx3aRuCabq7oxrYNP1tYy9qN1LjDsQ3ItgnyL@BZMnv83ol@vGbaEQULMY/Q4SZp0rTe0D7hkBoeUEHPS47gPcNihhRG9qJgZwztYPhVSGrYf56hmJFECRdd2BLrWjnWqIl@PG/UHDZIxDLgw9JTfxSLZvpgRDy/WbcH1IkXvWxyCSIlE8lSX9hcQdXPvuoljKkRrZPlSCG359o8Y3NisDzD6ayGXbq70EPYQq9MiofJpkja3ttU7u/TlKwSiZYMzWd2xnwkyCvLy4@/BXuyF6Z67s/CljVkUn6OugPa38cgw3HIx/vEubU913yPGeAe0olpvZkwExVJ1ZmxpiT6zouRjR/hIudChAyC1CP/7GSrjrqdwG02dFmRbOhcZKoP1hSOOiqzZor6X@9vDgL5m@09@PH2ZLKhEEwHv8Iq/3V/GAaxV54V38V6Bef45LtgOOxxMfFn6gJKlt2Y7nW2Y287MXiVXuEj37fZPWlp7yQxu3XNWQM3wseLHlJO43SvNHm8lyuW7K7u1Har6hEHrWwlziLTw7RjyZ4H7d59CLAM5nMJLB/sw/cwXKP/CQfXgCQysTdflmnjfBM3pghpzSecxUibhWrZWpwc/VbY8HuICOKmH4Yq7f5EFfkUtrq/48w6WS@UEvUJuXDQy1ItN53z0lyV3uFAF5CSIGQ08d5asOCpYSwl4V5z0Yd9FC62gls5PWPLST9fXC2sPEtx73ruyO2ePDtzHzXKaUWLr9/rhlfDm@bHi/7ldUt11ODX89vG@NNvSi0/UY@praWfJHJwcaWc52CtT@nfVfWswJyrEXzOUZCRAtmT3LBKLah4H156oBx@4E3zGjwkJrhUPeoaLoSL3ajcPVk5K/fKhVL3pHdWgpPfaLE8WiwuZvHiJ1pFScbIzfzJ6Axrqn3qGvSuFeJzcg5S7Rqi2DWE3rz2h@3@bmXvZeI0DgoAjsC0rTcfqEu66TlYs8H3xOsFN1l9TOYqcGwKClJqjr2CinB@5/NkHMc024QZjYpL2mx4y/@OndRcwbsajPr8xURjBGupL@0vqTnjxlTgEwUqctI2MRvhX0Bw4jJZXAzJ27FYUeeKoq4V4TvpWCBOUJPFYfo0nYZPIRDVvlwnZ6nQC/zGJZBAfvUvXE2tr3O2dWK10ONTPJhy@EN2mCic4REXIPRnwLcNaII195DdPlLUffwu4kHe8BnViP1k2EA@xZoivsD8W31m/yauv04EEMLPic7l6SNOrXmRIim@g3y4gFBnyY0/rhngVimDMofOAra0V46Bs6U40wjNajLR@7kbkFNoRf/pHuSK/GuqG1F5R4ozSfieWv8KQUseUv60gT@duFrWqpYz1UxhixRz36QGTrpoe/Q6oGk1VltBp0NICy3mYnLgkf17dfuLUfvhCdo8i5CX77mp77nEd0@@C1JxKY8W@LjQml0onfkcl/uq0nExd6qtsmLlxaORbnikksRlS/eVDb1Rv96OC29EQylcGX1YT3zIWV8@zBh9@fIgUSdi8Oj7iXzX/L2kRz7CMlH2RbJ9/E3pAQrYeFbbmkxwqddrd56ndGpu/QVsliZqKiXVOfmiMpOqrH0wtTghDQ7n/DxtN8oxlMWikTg8Z9Ib6y/SnlYynmcn0RAvxqmJNWOOWFTiNheZcLfssEjt8OcHFgiGCUZTZuZumMpjXXlsgUWpB6ZZ8YKcmuDUtckpXoZf5Bf8YyZ7EjlTLjP745xgfiudF@/mJIFY6D5IzyZTUprAXURe6k7ds4rEbY8nIc4WEnvWKXDUZiA@2C0cgz@I5IQtKIykmKJ79EVTOi5QNOx71xDi49fU3/KPUi990rEHneBWVbDN8NkLK5VwcB8F4ShEYCgOWhNeDQYd3DqywnfDLtQ6rMjSMq5bYojWyu6larDskfIunrRDOlXy1D4g38BAJP4QXl1cwJkMHrD9G4hWnLi0R16q0hvLgQbNmcdL4mYeKATfYAHcaV/YSMjIyewBpcOB3wi8FOloIWk/Kelqq61TlvJ5OvxGEHqMlrS1VOqfrtqNj1svcZ/7tFh4XLRIdq2vgwve4yexgxURyXxYQvTA5eKTVMq6G27I3XAOAF21i4X@LfFmcB30ekGqQisGFwxJaQ2D4XXQ9FKpgyC6BAZcsDJuJuGH3b8aNuRwh5Qun5gRXsKhK9dhxGH4i/VZrosbfFfmpnBpFd8201Bft5sgoPE4afVxO8wXFggTIPRApW4wIqI8clQSJb571riw7tLFQRRRA3FOrLuJiAy9/qjdoJHhk6xUh0DJNUjcWK85gQm11@j4cA72ZiEA95iYAgYBc5V0Hw4pfWn@Qzgo3TFzx@6bkcmT9OvzXKHpHgzbJH1jAvOocDULdxrgo1e1Q3W4v3P0rnJQVfT85mD/bW27uq023/MdNy7KOQ6verW/S9Iluk2XW/N9epGuHFLNNH9IVfbeq@rPbw6qh4dq/0DVXr/ZrRE0An9Q2TuqVQ9dVdvb2j3e5tt3gqD29o/Ubu117YiKHe273Kqplorrqf0d9bp6sPWKflY2a7u1o/fc4k7taA@N4Va/ot5UDo5qW8e7lQP15vjgzf5hVaFjqe3a4dZupfa6uu1R@9Smqr6t7h2pw1eV3d2Jju6/26seKDYSsHq5WSUsK5u0hUVL3M/t2kF16wgdip@2iHiE4K6rDt9Ut2p4qP5cpe5UDt67Guhh9Z@OqRB9VNuV15WX1LlU9htUoXHZOj6oIloSKHF4vHl4VDs6Pqqql/v720zrw@rB29pW9bCkUrv7h0yw48Oqq5BQkZsmGEQt@k7Pm8eHNaZbbe@I1ozjN7B3cGiQ3xFhCMsKVd1mAsMMAr0lIu0fvAdU0IEHwFXvXlXp/QFoytSqgAqwqNg6sotRg0TEI7ubaq/6crf2srq3VcXnfYB5VzusOjRgtUMUqMEg4z2xDjV6zL3GOBFe8kjMmjKc6/JwqtqOqmy/rQFzXZo44LCmuYXJtvVK09xDnF7rEKXdx5mB37UPVlrTr64DRKacPpGZfUYTRUza2t@u0oqsQ1ul4w/HtOqsToRSsr/RShN9pJ@JkDXN4Pzqot7utfrwMY2qycFHN7xwkSbIQY6V09Q92bL0@QpXyGTq9beVOm10D@t1x/2emgk0vlVDH4PfV8rRfUQOBuy8cfCztiZ0X08QauMnfdHJhnq4gEBJof5PYvrmdwNH5fPNQFeD8z4Am6OjUK5NLnGVQqKRnR2RHCZukk8m@HdbswNXzBrwXqOOc1JYRnKhfkj/9L7EP2RxsF6QdJbjrnwem1hGo/0pMM1IIxwSgf/REQnaLW7SC4Pg40W2YDeHPb930e83s45j6nDZEe0DL7LON6qfBxcT1XOT9RlZvnbW6QtCs@9mFSa6f9YkU3pcvCH3LIt/6iP@4xhsJOYDTk25KT6s1oeW2Z@kOiySXKVDW8C9ggcZOt/rys@1d9jNFZaelCbev4rey9yCvSBi2NKCd8L1zvjPqzMpQBOMY3EQSdo6QkY@b9Ux9iZR4RsqeIlCN@0mLH9orb4MeF0nkpAie@V37DaxGg/btzb2JIdfHlRebx7v7JDoBLZPVpefrpRSUditn135@x7tcJhZjjo2oHWc9DT@ZM2SLVJ8eKZYUb5j9mcGzudREPHbzaDxS8R5iOw2kpZMEGTobohMST2Y6KUD0CGtOADHg5Th15kzUzNANtFVB73p@res4vukKzEPaGOWzphH7Rb/AHY0/c0UjzqkGUizGAfeJc6l3QXLvfSOMRXlzQ0H7kERL234WMK4RTTgoy62n4V3Lf/SvG2NYiimjJivPOxck5B4MImFMnYVPZnZbzjOiD4A5uhh9OZnzW/0@F4HuONwd344qowOiYw7UU2cU8eH0brTJxryGfJpIKiaaWld4ZTf0Ujx3NPHyVFgEGs2MCpIDgMb3yTgUhRHZLJJtoB9seCoz8KpCN4BOCXNsfo3ce6s7mgoJRM/RP82USmUwIqCnAjVbqI2UqbI@yiOhSFngkx/ih4M/x9Ikxnw12nHSdBjallBAL@LkgxVaEXbVyZK@8ZcNFi3GzE17VfvYzBf7YG5jDqmb29uxb@GSKBHZ2xevOewh63sDAKAyXGwYc/fyCTt0qet04u0o6vjnqTX6A6ySq8VZqmYgptbOXNZ7XLN3Qp@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@461Pv8e8aI4Oddi/hj8KgzHtABr59m2eYdSzf@lf9upb/Y5/0e63fdqnIQb8rUg8PI75EQN2MezfhJxCiD80rULNcfws8WUkDBt@R/eSJSs0VzgKBlnbTGE0HFcuJUwEn5zDCDBOX8r8PZiMkRbVebIcV0ol/U/ZHq/olO6s@7g4q7Lc6AOAFnAbExYU4kM6Yscky/m0NFXg/L4CFo7nKqd85w6LvQTGz4hEfA2TwNggM2WWYHcCO7M7MT5p3rpNjkE4RKClYDtAOpwwy69dHxmhSYo8h6XAmiquFqyqcotyiziEeBjfTe6lp/9g7AmBP4F@8fEsbpnFCCziWibaUij7FR1llHBh88A2y2iWxCTF2hftnuV@yBkobiehJj@P76IGW/6QUqTD7E1xJWZkljY@yHSXrZPIqY8dLCoLasHhuB1QQSqjbOFuhg2@ZT/Lkx@XuHJyBsG0pSFnLaTvIlWDqIScuxPmtTbKElP52zNmael7R22CgOVZJmdW7uds2mgu7IHSlvUV11r9IQnj9AT1tKnHQjjqDxa@k3p3yo6Zkdlm0brhON80BBZmK9Ni@ajJpC2P8TgupSbxmWCaJMXY0ox4CNtXfo7YfJKIt@U65lu5Pv4GHe6iWWw3FS0q0Xg3Ze5jUbyGRa9ZaKIpxbgjSGkpen9Sp47X75YgGqZsr@osMeoQGfWxPFqgJsgUUen7KcTcp3GfoEeTKId2m0Q7e3zuJOqkkZwJeWo@JYJcgp4I3A6nTZJLgxaMLxAmTjTcSEhFCuetO@arvGLuHEGG8UEAQisOcvE5lJzgxoM1wUecHaCVrcNaqAhJRE8btoVDFPQ/IhhH5deHO9rioT7OFc9KAuk2gkS7Ci51HyTjb04/T@q3DGWKFDTFZ5Ai6tGUbLr8/l792b5QOYIgtfmztvQtuOiMoxYJG/rH/lS/hQ4cN6VrJmZUciLUWTTQXKBdykUnkO0qtL/2UDge1g16GtEGQl5n8WdR10A475VCRG1UuW2OUcTR5JbZ5qjchlSJGUp@g/x6KoqqyxtXAhAIxlS/XCQICGvK2ONSgEPv2JyXQFSPEVUsFzEt6SVHRY3tPGd8B1F1gSfLVonCrBLPbBi5mUBIsZhdJkaEdJbZRWIotNDNxMUq8XR2f@ISpBAb3heK01DoUUnSMBo5ISAnmy44sUQ5KSq3oDmYPz5ZdhIfI/7mr88K1tfC5FeiT4ThSa44@XW1kPiaaHZpKVk1UZPo4ditJj4SKRwb4Ugq/Ln/2DXFDnke2YRam4yElqHts5EMnHaZtG/zfg3VOjtlGx3DwLM9w832qy4pVhJB2e8PwK4W@MoAsdv/dG@NZarBROcK4Lh0xtklKxtC1ljTWOrRLex0TaS9KECB2dP2W@rt0c5OIuzr@dgYGnWD4XKhUAATn9vB741tNY6S2v18snS@ddXp5Ac3fxm@Pc@z7A8CTgmwZnbQAQ0JTYrQ6w8vJDMEcKCiKJ3TjqzY61@1WnYKBtxQYvBo2KSkjoageAFqR0Yvb4/4AIhB6gX2F3QQ/ftFRbPvxhdFU0Mx11BUGybB12lze0bkwYsW7LOjmyoGBsFsrJlo3XLKG5@xgiCzCQ8Why92PsfmyelXQafTd9U7JCFGpIC5r5MVdnbsCgUpghtG9u69CjkerauC63bH8itGEZvXAc4sTCbPhIkLj9j4B8FF9XaQTZ98SNOyQl1eRDcXEZ/aVemLtKODxX8HWOFDQvu7Snf9QbbBdJosTEu9nsHxE2H0uOjO3Pskijh8JqZp9u3SIOpsdD0O1kBdd1gXMLHseXi5J3cUj4ibPr0ttkDDgsDQOCHmyvfVgKvZP04sXo9are@TipwGQAb2hySiZEL5cwKR7wB4BurpR/REFO2/5mha70wEFBEFB8k6puUOKtRRIZV62Cj/dpOtVCpqfrC4qCqVTXrI5VRls6K28WJzU23T7038/qm8tLxcEpm77Xyml5vm5Ve1STD4hHOxcTncpp/0rQy/MVhrY4jn8@V5tzRfL69vlML8SWUTbv309J//8j//81//V76if/w7fmzyj5MPUSHP8/Lzjc/zP30t4ffJ9tnC/PnJ/OBs4aIELvsbRw3v10Y5PzYf9YbnqYysAtZbtiM1@2yOPqOrKpMCsOsPP5J0WVOZRpjP6LehZI5iGZtpBNb7AH6U57SFN0kHJrfyhESGgI5xHE@j0whggEfrDVGScIEdqNSXuxVzcI9wMFGB6FYloyPxsM56HcCnJY6kAF9cWrFy7V4Y9HACfs06r3QvlfLpb3tU1/yb//A6vNjs36pHp1n1qKAeuepROs1/iivP6K0zn2/DO1eK0XYgnXbpS3y1ADNDFbZZ0eP9A@famSB3KjXPKXsAyYSp4MLiBedGuz92lpGEa@FFag55OJUckfAlE6pkPs/3vtKwfKYSX9MJVxtWFOp6F8ONWTcq0fhCBfJDMQSIW@4KQdb61CRu@tgjGU9580aPdYqzCTFgkPXg5Q7Pe7ygtWi@p22eE3sppDli83l5i7WxJM7QjDa@SPsxAnyhItvJAnsSLmQWUmLlbfWSuyle2Hb/NPOJrcM4GBnbdKn0u7KYQKy5bcLN97RfizbklusVlW5H1ytWU@lJ22@Vsqp0rzqj9kC7K3DrmFCfo9a@ykzCiDIggSMx@9emZxgfFJhIURPDIsmyxqrZR9dlJvS0azoNsOPJzZFFhPyHLM3tLxNz28mzl4hhB@EBRioy5Wv57U6oo64MmdgX/vAc2QH9FidUG8m9GZ/nIZ/qBMb9VoS0x5DZ5Dyez9SVzGDoX3R9V2X2@kdDf1yjZYs0n1HDc6iHCMEEJDD5dNOzumcQlh7pIWGKRF1hyyEkL@iMdXo0Gdt05HOCITVTQYddwSRIsBNTMviSGKsJOsZc/QODYKM8Jbyj20gtYlnywtJIQ0rbbjM8zaamTsq0YM@daOKkU4JqNDMNL@hKV1hou3zxS5K8gxgBuu209gLUrggrz9A@VqeLoOcnFqdBJ2Uc/fMlJesi5jOnohRrpJTJk1qMM94BK9IjPySjQMjaZMIZpeay2bnTUKdzy9jrCAf5jmzx875qRwnoOIEZe4ao415bhOXEChXnwPBUjS3/CUKr418QfuMbfwxWPM1knz/IOycfTntnj7KnvS@nnxzGRItks8rmVEZfZhuJpecKrYx5N/HTWKWFJtTgaS9Z4LSnxIfFIgEhks@efMiffckTQqcZpKQ/zQhBEkMGTPL3t5cH@PwUmpkkFvlMas555JjBzz4vOorWVv6LMZQXjvwlLMymko/paZ8zbBEo9tP97UpcTsL86lLhyVLxCe2ELoLb3DC4wnqbC6/Og1tSJUJsZ2npOf2U4IYEIb7ehn6JXt5SPyWtifiehNpJSYtQPc25nVTEVlTHE56g8kRlDpcKFxcnKuPj8hEbflcRy5myHAtKTAct7sti/Qz7XbTjh5Brk94hwpGwMhAbET5CzQGySb5yF4c6ZrossJ@Tp7YQu5WB0PDmM9Zq0ev3clpZc7yFEpRoeM10Vgurhck5OjVFEzN0XitTCw9UceP50//4t/3fMqPMxlL@3ZD@jjK/ZVZWM/JID/Trsfl1ndnIrKPYytfMOE97YHp8@h//m@pv/IXg4Mt4nf7ZWDawVsaZjVyZq3zJbKzQQ3Fpidr9P//8z9SHedmxIRfrfN1VjFjJUGTL7zHv0ndVQy9lW7oQixV2zAIMsTCkvTn9gGHU7dJqgY/pMtqq4jrQka@MPYpe4tkwa8SmQnKSYewpSDOSCmU0kBOQxoSipSzbDWO2AeaN0VS/PPRWQtoB/KLNOaImI9ONhyFMhuZlW0QDmJUWaT8vDxuF5@nIvGMtbWxKSkaFxNZOy9rVxyVihzf9YNRuJK0kzHTtNvyb4NwDH3pB84r2VL2w0/91mL8mluwWl1bzLRzu59mOOz9gSLnB2PtEiqBOBkQbQzY6ddWQRqDfRQgvl7MFkUK/E91JmXySpGUPgoacYSVzElMR8fFz5XoY3fFiVTrL/5ICj8yZOhGklSvttEc19w/WVHoxKijleM/rAJs3bByrQ2DkxBp2wLLJS3EfcDpo@uNVhhfshMS1EHVdinh@s1n39bdsai5tUqW5qbnLoDMop1sS3h2xU3FjoukvauadUHJtnCDkcizoAKsbjHzaopfT/Ab78bgFhEnRd61RqLiYrC1dVu/qm2XOunJP0zfS9A2NKLSEuJ2IZ6xobMouJrKljKPKYVDHldrMhqm10CRtHnr8BxiEMiy1FtwSdHfYA5KoFndHW5XZw@byXph45CYQnz05WpTM1alM7PzomhLiQQ3dCe160hgJCETBXYOFMv0@FA@Iskkz2u6lJJ7fxGcT30OD4T7sI5SoHbZOgo/KstS7Ru6b9oh9KRWRQMeVtW2wU7J6RKCjEFtRCto0Dl7SDliqtcabLS5ohmON00CbkFDptJxTnTRUlF62pbPXSqIIepEuFJceP1leebr6DFnO5nRvZ4NBJQ@7gMGlTzBYo87SJhvvy@X0QlpeIQX1dJOAPgssLuBg1nXjOCbs843zoFwsaGCFNMO64TQaUl0fVzLIGOIw8LAi0B4lO0xns8/XTtCxs9Om84X@J/428QGZ4Uw4Wl9Ib43DmzgyVaorAQfKLJg5KE72MSKoOPqLXTbotw4QbSKArauwPTW0iwgQo8th/@ri0uYOT4e2OqIJQwTnuNTYQb0MRnGAMQsr6KL6wKFmeV@UDbyT6R7AKBdLAnQ@AU7TTMet9LWlKWbHAi1CiKwJj1VcIVqmozY7M3f2@qq6tz2JWMZOQ8dwPduylZQ7jmSGADLI1Wt194ioq6NdsCuplkluIqoyC7gCyhXZHd6Hr3QDiagtqhhZzXrDKHsfWYrMi3Fo07gqjSPwmgGzWPg2KY1fq@kFCGIEoT5NioSYG93n2CSLcbIHGfMUvJxes2xEX7fDkAPM6cbSjrYo5UKcVWAudQdAnNsU0tKRwhpGlB@rnHhZRhvJHMUrGkcD2gw52qkGM0tymgm2ug0lADayjhtaoP@1vS1XbVfpn5132y4U5c3KX9HvKMXz3fgWNb7FNVXbMUNgR4tlm1vYTP0GFyViloIOGBsjCOHbkqyIQRw1oFrb0bSXSX2SmNtnMVeAXX2thJvTUT1JEOiFz0Dm9OY9CsXB7jr8bk0Or6YlTRRSRU8LOeK6f2JbNJmLW40gCSm/A8TSJIgoUEvM7XMxw4sFOmvevt67GMau7czm6QTLyoaK1PadPJE9ybN3UuY@tljSbLG0hnG8jy@Yb@/ljfOg1de@aBFzfIM3Hvwx3sh9P3Pk/lswR/Ufwx2PNXc8XoPsEe6IwoazRyenYe/P4JjzMa/B9Wb7oo3zoZb1E50ouBYAFnjAED6k9LFYQN/uECcqO/vD4uR6BCOhpWU4Bvyhzj/RnX@yBpnLj9vBf9XO5/7OnV/WnV9ew1ozY@S1ameFW//79DhWCbPJFzOHF@quFHP@aE9XdE9X1rCazhjm/@89zf0/6ulT3dOna4iYIBcOEr7@fm4WTaRyuFWrxeYWXkoH7coij/1srnSw92qW07R5aHWuwssytHX1h/Ff1fivQhrxE9LQ4S4isg2N9vKyPRVnedEs@ZRDwclKeiL9NZHRrf7qBSvej@gFSoQ0H2wN9UaFFHJXPsa3TV6sP8bSN1p8vhdnke06WSYuzq0NtOwIi048xUXz1Ukyl1aidWWbYyCrraOD3cX/IWTo@h@1Fxohj6G9CTods5LYW7CjKOqU7ozVHcA@1HuOBKtocjKyI@3tHbHL3N1SjQNbTKyLszcJctWG@z/aS3Whb1hZuXFkRLTxdH2zq4JprtleyBvquxSa3WXd4z/Epc80lz5bUwd6Y3AXqXx94Kd5Md6nLS0v37cGSC0PfzABCy6Vv2dW/V8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/6ulm9)

More Raven docs are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081225181657/https://mythago.net/manual.html).

Raven has `''` strings without escapes, so it sees Ring code `put 294 bye`.
Ring `""` strings also don't have escapes, unlike Raven, which is used to separate the two:

```
"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye!
```

`!` detokenizes `bye` in Moorhenses. ``` `` ``` works inside `""` strings in shells, so it still needs to be escaped. `\` is a valid
identifier character in Ring, so first `!` cannot be removed.

`360 print` [should work](https://web.archive.org/web/20070828231404/http://mythago.net/manual.rv?word=print), but fails with buffer overflow,
so `"360" print` is used.

Answer (score 1):

## 367. Befunge-98 ([JSFunge-98](https://gitlab.com/PurkkaKoodari/jsfunge-98)), 16168 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕ=1\0C0<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'@,,,"285"z;@,,,"366";k09<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"763",,,@;z"482",,,@9
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;@,,,"364_";# _'1:,,@9
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L39c@PadSD4o8vI/BFXoF6TFAmAAL9JkWq1Wv1advdTW1K/92KSzQZJkEQLBNgAKZEtqcv27HrjJDOb8ThTjpPJczybWWczVZOd2tk4O8lMVbI/TqXmp/wBnY@trdRW/B94zzkXAEGJlLqdSdXU1kIicHE/zr333HPPPed@HHR0b/izn8XwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nuJx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@8w03N71FBr79OTRo@u@WfZVybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrpwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//kYZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@w1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79kvsoEBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmNfAVXheulQfUCiGZ1Cv6a3KhvA8C1JcJfQj0qCAYqMAboLcgZ0QtAyy@VeR2eXwD1cJs32uCoSqCSqnAvzMuxemJePCCxLtL4yz8Jzu@SQIqMa1gCjU81pkFhC4HtighKK4KEo/tiKHiTt8TCSa7jn1KZ5OJbgokiSXYTCLwwACSqMCcKH2TUnbV9cuXcvEFw2ajUgNpCmgG32klGNNpiwlIFTQ2SZpBE/E3niHE@wbySSUF@MfMVLA2ITUGqtzi4mQxd6HL1fCRAJ0CrYSMkBYv12/sQ8nfauN7SNnhhJxF4HQpPZnYhVAQZ/3htqt2E1voRV0HrjiFUkXkxPoG8QL/lig4p@NNfwUPyt@UWJtHACS@DT6koU8aS@34Kg9@ZdyxcJuAs6O@dGHSj@qT@RFTKitC8TBJ32Rk/lQLA7cDjs2e7J45rfF3mg0jHtypKH5XR1i7w3MboYpH1y8OBo9@gX2ytgWGanct1DMXOlAg6105k0sKdKTtYqm1EYC8AP27fDxoTLcUTBD2aSM4uISvMuDC6zAJ2HR1@9jhKQhBAdlAO48XdNpOFxQOgSOro3vDYIs0EqBVmGSYK4TDpgAczQgUXHcD0oz7PpmzfYeNcLNfb9sWTWVOcAAk/lwA7SyRh4TQALgjp9PiJSWpBCTRsXGhauaMygPB@j1Hy9MCRKR0jm48NH@0c1AuvPq0kURfEmIEvpbk8GmremoIKvigPsD1xdlpIXBUd5msq6EsHd7hKCF23L1sAHAKjryA6TrFFQNW8IZd@7XjfylbohBdA7QbguV0bloe6HFjRSDhziuqjyrhpFKWAxWIVeK0esMHR52Orm80YxV44OW91Fnr0oUFoUgHEgkBtdCDr1JPSRF1KkL1b7xT9@cqPgHgmRoApIQck8i8mUl2cJqL1IJot7yh5oaI5lyJ8RxxOZmFSUeLAuIHc9Uj4j8fdn5iSRSfKnmoS4kPvu7oH2MIjsT1nTTAYpDaiL48jk9nF9r@sBjdiO5QwctgVpuHQYZAhi09pq7g4c@0YL6eiJVY3hEiHwX5y40ccw1phvSHGkVFF1lS826rZ3DlxaLWQRSYQhAqVQfPmVfqYDuhb1Pj74@j4MImo@kwndGboABZE0hC50dSO@5MEkyEj2y7OyguFy4Y3eHgRIkfU6rLTP6MKEu4vglZ7EMWVlZfyVRfqKcwPjr5z5NdICH05a4Iig7OCTZ08OPtl/uvt5c6Ll80vvuUy5AIiD/DogC8lDjjfsrVu8a2K1EFwM@oaL3Qu4wBQUlGC1aOq5wLhljCLzAqyhGr7QmviKM7TjXvJ6Zc4xVHpldzkJPcXOx6P6CUHR7lmojLh8tRrHc6Sf4WQy9iqKAr18OO3IoLQqr7qOpQ8USgcDg2UpKqouB4c4r@GtSgGF8eYGT8Ent0B0mNMMom6NHFBeaM0bWQNLcPA0a2WZgyHowrgwbrhJOaRgqo3SAw0BdGUlrBsxYHoD3PrPoJ1ETtpfVrUSp2s1o@UUMYi21P0h7kbfANUpAaMVoCJ57ZU17zXvsTlwaYR0HUiMyVs0yeExHAssBoIkzZqinh8gh7gFzpciryAcvZ7ibC5wKSWfyRXVQl4BtQzUNJBZJZxzk0b6pDuUJo4E8CSnT/MGESrse13d7stbviMoLMh9H0FVs40XzabdAgG9eY/KhuvOjXmrobaSVXYzyZYfP1kF6l2qHtJu4AG0S04gTXqyNfysp99kZz2delePKZPR2B9zpDF7uguC1BsH@HXPiPY9TKBEA5WtpbgKRn6rrJgQsjCpgDfElAIdCkZaID0FyyWB0IviIVAO8K1IAraYzeD14Ps7InwElW6ke9OJe7RGgnINzpZ6Y0AiTTZ3kUt7OD84gdExpHzk0tC4yKTZuRHHeXTd47OVkMhf4w/Sg64WQqBZ@XBG2g53NQARUCpSz4FzAF3htOlwMcuISj9QGmRIZcLJB5AgbFo9GACfgcS8Iru8Ijwn8lmu0qntnNsIrWOwktQxJ3yy35m6uNZt9qJ1g@hZjccBaFS5CF@nRfGO0eWzrDwx1QKUQJ2NjJGDUwkgXRErMKgKOl9QR13Qwxlr6FYZCVcMAb7E7u8BF@safL5IGqESBSS1z@ITV9mVvq7o0hug5ltkK6x8pIn9Rj8JELC8vYFmSfwZUJJOnBFF@ozmWzDwQSDuCrhiCDUGChP1mjM27Os6H9cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0EV8Y2MjXonX42lw7YBrG1076EqBa4dcErkwnowuSpEmF4Y2KAX6teJXjQDyLNlCGpih5PDGHCf0RqWSbaX1huo/NXwmoSkA8xBbwgfAiSdrNXQmk2L9HNdsQH6P1H0Paee465pjHwVfAYGAv/s4yBISQL1Had41qqib3o6RUc0FpdFAETPhxpuNTLPVvGj2Us2reBpTJ6t6DfRDYF6TxEgeuM50DIJbI1eRgLclG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkZ5MflRKpnSO60TcAJpKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQTn6JmgZlpWIyxclyL@TbCVTcUibjKeBLdficcALLTh6VGmcEeBE9MicASqhY8IQF11TIAZJi1PYXb9ujIdzNxohnHUDKRtn0Bd7VXBLD3LxKJd8w9NHBbolTT@Qe3k8EG5x8g7lpfGcc3eBl7SpLO2MCsbdM6k/cia68qkMSpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkpBAOiar91PSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQzB18T4ZTYJbB9rQ0UJU5Fozu0GHxzfsAnYXrPTiU4NKVxBfAAgC9rgw/ZKIoleBiCUgXtKHIBL5IW7FoVkalQnDWE8zN5wvj13KYW5XSsAxmZA5sxzUkQAmkEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQBzXzdWJfwQ2lIQ8XbNIAjPrIcnXDL2XVkPWg8iqQH/RySHBk9wQL@0Qf2KPO2cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNogJ9bC1hr5AYrjjXvyZAZJhQQOuNFArt2B0HnOepqmFbr5fiUIQ6oAZA@hkVArtUHFDYIkFQKTfiPv82mhQEf/5PDhPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U5Epfbzoy7EGa7QM9mbYzMgENQfo3p9aR40y4lg8v62ZmuNJsjqaWTnM@16dlbk3XdTqORVNBtyVdxJ@6nm7pfBIqCN399CnI@s9PjmtyJRJJ0c9Gt@aN85Crs@X4PIiuOdJ6a7A85HHCFDfzIo5bwa5PZDN@QAEDpv6eT2ijwL@I/kGXwjUU37@E/iPc7wmysj@LQK@hpx@xTBFxDyhuePM9L9TMFfqv1cHCeCrF44LjorQXqkb@Z5N@f8k7S96nErIma@GdI2@@F3RJR4wWKc8j4cbQpThRQAWKE@4PXRuvSPH47hY5XFl8Gm5CGBpWsLR4BBILLp/BoG@hXAVKC4rofA@nARL2GFdJiHXj2hvrghDq3ZjPgM42lnhsIbZBHQgGNwVFGmFTYf7cd5W6kO34a5YeZ6sO6Pw0rbJd56vcqFO5XJ1T@Kz8ZhtAbNerwYa7ddEwp3g8jEZQqWyQgqpJC/s3qhpu0/Bosl2gJFXBU0CdmGkZqTkr7rcu44pHaOgzsdmcfZTRPge9BHdLbt5TBkaV9jitwVc1CIn7MmxnziSQ@DAWn7juDoHPsNRsGZXQPlO771g9ia@SAcEwrl9hA/mbFMJdnP5mXcN0gw2ctIOWJ0X@Gtn7eQPutSat34wQ2S0aAoLuc8EuT9Nnl6wBQ96Z7I0tc9JiV/LEaQ/9nVL29X2lXAZ1XX3uCf4elxrbPfr400amxSEIIx1Xvkq8FWfB9mQQnEFQwn3k4MKdOhNzQpIA7UQwsb6qDIWa0SIJFB9g8AyqLMzIrxEW/dK4XNSlb4CmmjCw5N58lGZG8kruW/pkYtic5vjy43p083UiP5saZb/jLzpUWIZWZkAyNTEMilhlxycP94@OZKBcLxHfxxWcCnRHvTsEAWVdpQNMRitfYR/14uwjTJNEtV2ArgbaR9tPD0RdBaIH/QNyR94xMNwEeCZx8aUL3rTeRQm5hOYjCPdbdSeEoxBYwkhCnQhYZWX5n9tc1fLLWQGKTxEmAd2JexXArZmUp7b5WvZgoCG5FaLEubIK40VtM0FcbFNN@hvqRrh0DBoWCY1Qg0aDSW@Ay0FkkbVaVb4HAOKiAuYOELuiSE1Bu9hratD0NfAGkYYg@Mlrb9mLRkYqt1Kbq0DR5jJ/AzqvfwQuQlgG7Rkrs91MUH@/0ZF5GfhaIOfcz0mdvnb6osI2uUPkc84UPdgwRUyH9lct75Na3oUFnQxZCU3FYEUClhDzjwf4NEvhxPlB58Fk5JFIsosQ6RqinF1eEg7ZpsYIh@BSGW@Mq0D7BMb0xIHaPPGPBkSlA@qt/kYS7LNNQQzUrOWVWgzhIrxydk06lc7EaDouHZr2qUPrPaGrnZHVPEqEYerRqXUzJW5CpdtS1LAMPK62rnTeqNOn24oItOzhL6iTB02o@7IwCJG6ckQPmltfkfPyJpKlbP3tqTTSgptJr@@IKZVLFLnf6ZjrogIScF9Y8FwRDZgU0rMm52Q1OGuAUzEwHgHj4trLourX9x@xJbz7@2j953/@Rg/wf7N1hjBQ4Mxj6GjD0I0tJfXXNpafFF/otrph@QT51DJ1Qgy57gLZ1V2okm6FjtWgaRFekmD4H@GSgt/iQJt4A6nxFjLjJecrgsFzdSarFtVsYJnddXGv7cfiWdHyDyh2PUICF4JMgxIR6@KNYMz4EkxExUY2dnehgk1TjIiZt/twOpnyOwiudzaiOcbfbX3Tj5nJ6x3VUPjO9Vua3NVPpz1HGp8OQjm1sCLuova0BiyBOOAvB7fRubr6vIJ8J3jwXBdtMbQp5/S4iyo8e@qNpQ5p4T3@Rh1hdEsOrsXv66KY/uG90LEea6ZFt/ekRB86EIq/G0LBvaZSBGnmNTRbemeOMsjww6ks3FkAHKfWTaUy2TVLy@Px@vSoSVL6cnl16pnc5fhYNUeg8P2sEp9Fowr7O1zvaFUYrsyRbklaL@Jcy8xXbUy4ETVc06Q0ePiCTmDcSuQ4IHWnlu4uXLeQ@KIcwTLCuhlpf9h4ZnYdEAfGTC3KqhYMHZEBg1hmsDVukRFuJ6ZbZPuDuQqNwXESKXStZgFOd4JbRtfQ1HswNL5VEzfERohEdtZhquuc42@t@DAE1ZTfV49ob1aW6j2Yk2R1LR3G8bXDwdLkIE4@3kGo56Zn0G01Yk9XFnTStVb6L3eBYNovOo13F1l7puV47JjutyFo4AIW@H01QUdxaeq2RJPhUfctPCjY47BoUN0aOFahNFB0uK1t9anbR77vP9@Xw4UcSlXv4FCB@OPYqv9cy9dPFff0rgaiA4su7m@NOG8ZYlexKX/tZX3tQDHAhbvVNXuUKVFKWeFTfWsyxiWXc30ePH@OoWMdaoOhYzwncRqkO0xQLoFj4nIR@@fJLXd7br33Y0o3wBbvqkSkcU8tAwYrut9oUqZl1A9MoWYy78@i@tbUmBorFY3DzisDj9XfomS8f6EyfjU2/Zl6XBzAoylhrDe@ZvhepcZxGt9uZSa6ZXaNu0WZZaY2Bul7jKrzM3A8Q8fNFAN7Ol5q1SXtzD66HWXDcdClnd5S6TDkQ/lQ6Q5JaUk@9wz63aoxcQ0PN4jV8plMxhdgIisuSy@3aVLZMO0rk9@XMiafRc6LuLjK5kacq/MgtES3IK5lQdo6xZ4il8uKbdrGZI739@SmHcexPqSlgKnigWEHtFWJttre1mI3xB3/EAlbTF14OOHR6a@btOCjja9bAn5Qab6t0aNLQu/VmhIueo5wQWr59fbpm8gC01254OFWnBPim2@t9bKkPxuiyiW5eGuv4xKq0zEsnT9mhdxt8Mpy9lZ4y0zDX6zFxV2@pLtYio9dY0rjOSDL7IGWMjRGBr3eIuXrPTSR4T/WRpo5@FsXPDOMrjLbN7rrIoxN4As23pfWkCPC0sSxQb@a4D4/1FMs3Enq@67jwMGq30okH4z0gcFtttzGKRcTFribhqt1C@fqqYsK30HThWQLYxzrSQI61akx94LnSoBP511o1@no7um2a52/i3Og79Hb121hvTnE2kNnaA@NId83Hr6t6xxAjxNuY@e2okOpB0PcyjYeL21xj@LTcizrffCJrJEzSsfpryzTPh5@xZNbHwSXn7T3H3dO3ukTzjvQsbbXDI0pjEueM3HGhkRv66JaONHD7@t4aLBI/fPOIN2q5wNGgufPC/9O3XKgO5PxmB7tsTX16EZJJTqzfJfc1OdbU2hTpOMO5DfOqCP7nrK/b4WWwFezmI456Q7x0DinbGPgdLpD865C@4YqlGDKh7@@l@6KmDGZ9BC9ZcsE9LpzGemlFg0/xsfBukb3Z4/4sBY6bpFXVs3Q0bFsaayfdj0@G4ouVsEJ4Uhv5Ie3K3T8vfJ6ak4WQCN7mcLpXb4sgY51Zfd3T6yVrOiMxIIN@7sq1lIpCekokEtGBgQedV22y/vcIl0sm@W3dQWK1pJKFNmX8iHo9vf@0OygGZm3Bf8l@lratLRykLOH04F3k2Hy6foeiGh4Wz9tQXuZI1PWMGbptv9Yh2bNUvCQIzzbIHNNjVvXVPK3LqpQPNWSdMeERxse0HTTtXNoljn2@J1J/bVLcf5eJtDFr68XctzMVyvTfsP0jD5fAkHXXSLiyHFxJzLIIFIXV9JxBh2ZORe8OOOynQEwdclii8hB3HViy8ptQqubPxwzpc8/MQY67rV@Yk5ws@YKqiCSXbW96E7YX5vqnvm1KdRsHbGhxQa@DOlGj/bj2wp4T/WB2X281BBhIX0E@zs9@WOJ/NHrZlucD00PdzSFjlsmppDkOBEj1bVBb1gR8/q8fWisYtGB@DHIlbFXza074zmeFpuT67ZpdXNCs6z@c53quG4T2K2FOJ@OxlPPf6wuA@2Zis5Cj07J3zs3Abj0GlgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFaQwf1BcONdJ4183LWfAvl7KMBDaQAhD4XwF4TyA4fkZbshx7RWUSHm/57InTnRILq/Ya2hbI8sk0zYnt8/mTCa4OSd4YmX4yIEnFJQneJfvfygE6WQ1Rp7cLesvjibfMb4D5R07U7droDO0NxJVC/xcjb1g9zGe6HDQXsp5VEvrOhZ0L3BYK7tM17GnE8md2reOCoVbR4UKWpuKkAFLfG3/6fNklBpot/ZdUmhgj2zhWrth4BqRmTYIYuv56HLsQJd4yO0kHdFW4TvS7KIxpy6x64fOKn3n2RwGkPdWmID5T0cPjS4uG96Z9yfOU8d2YDQaA6McHRn8zP/SRo/VCTHZEzzVDvjp3ZnNMYFdMwhxaUMfGx1oX2vhep@xiAN@qE/0NUMRzQ2S/he67qQV0@oY7iua9Iu416m0ywV6bMxIt1hPMLwPSpNul4vEOB@31EeWVmy8sePY/E7cNgMP9entXAWGArq9/0K5jBvxl@YFVupny1U9POO7RIweN0qxrq6u0XEsfr9lT5Jt8j0BumsanvIEbRyQXyHHJJC@vFt5SPFWHrJQjUCSPdM9WqRfrWosQKqzD9gCNNTdroMrYb7jlt05EcMEd7DpcG8/3zjQAcTPgGPp3alvLPSuYlmjzohuaxWGSGseGR08FdQhax4TfXazMfnMkG/KILKjKzQAELAr7NQFlngG2kjy7mFrSY9axqo5phtx6rXL5bRZR7JNo/tGx1kzh/C1mJteCoc6K5@Qc81cdaQb0SyyotNJ95U9aXnrGgg0liFNhi7o/MrktuntwMzKivWQ6cjAReblVZi1oqvjDamyzur19JC5uobk2/oDXhLa/ePyobS7VvJE8PB/@OArCgzC7UIuMD0CrOvuFXwo/NS1/cf7UOAzx5v0zdkhlBtPAaxjJ1itPCSBB@8Z6NpaVwloPXtq8dmHQWTf1ahH6phEVpglySJ2PTEkwz6TyBDc7GaNHH7oS9lF670Toyf5dhBwpUF6Epz/CqP5zxULqFHeiJs9VYUjdlbI@ds/VyH3POAMIG85E2ns0VMZe88OnhyeyGNPXTk@7Q7xdMQNOW7JsIJWykSmpF7pbmS9k29H65neRHlwrEp7Tw5kjLAG33xFQ4IHrswtPdbOewZWXBV9rRaEocZktYD4@OTpk9TiiCZL7A1dZ2Qko8F7x8dpPGnyleOVwdHUj6B39J3Z2uQH@6qaXEG@z21aHVzHPVfktA7SiQHaKBDjY26X5U7hquuMjd7JfGx8CoMncnDvPbMvrK3kJ/qZOcBeyMprEUUdlZXlQi4Z2ZkNyrbhhs917XlqjpFbdumh8Mfa7SgoOWQVN7taerhtxf@6FMMy/k6ED0ukZm5Sa9SOsKJ7f9@Cqaq6Ds/Heh/aleXXNtZyhFXrw5Zz9h5LyYavvEihlzQBqpLMO/eRF6URsG4Fbzg973uCs7N2G8xtAELvwsoOf27Yc92WaC3rNvGiAqlxU9utUb5uvMeCVLjD5wyNla9c4wu31LNEl5zJOzI@cSNJ9vYeHNyV4MjH5e2xPv7kOXume2iE5PaI0RIb71HihWT0SsJ5K7SAt3Y5tecCKO1WeIPx6v5cYce623Ps@ezuRTg6g4pDOxkXDmHhG0UyLHNmrhqrunxe69nqbUZ35c0PcTjzJTk4apzGB/Tu2/9MVTMZMj2ETzXDX@9omaCDswS69Dnas4sGnRyErKGLcosMHsmV2ugTY4bbUfhs8CqlfuX4Vrhl7Csm1w8nt4WVbgnL3ZLfjTD0ZFk5o94CMH9LGMvLYfATxzofOvKe7hreiv3HKwt0W0XKt1SkHOHOvrV0Wlj03etFfDy64D9WUuuJMXFz46HTMXMr67DbRyOT7CkaS78Z7m@n0F3a3jJw/CMf/H11fudTY2VGT/U3qwOI05yuDAImaAyndCTiZvDyAmkHZF7DHpjcviJ74Ez26e0WxSw88bx6L4I5fjgdry8x8Eb8JMV1dr4U8TPQmZ1zjz3Ao3ELMX2F7o/741b7r5NpWTgxiGZGH5/sBtR1eKxokRwXpfj82ZI3Hh6dHB5H/FxjNlun9EqzdTrkypBFrp@c5Jay3a6/OFuBrPXnjUDcAH4cPtfKQZzZfeX4JktA9W04GVlByFd0ezFjutRgPWdCJw1XBj6bz2gb5cqWHvJdbKvC3O4K7yXFHgZk04S8PaXdRsv67fY6qjwxPqe1BxCD2ISLJRyob3jJmOWGQQkpydqO6pwuhJ@l4h6Ph6Y9Wxk0WpeGdpEmXnmru8EuO7acc/YktCq0jj1oq4HrZ4a9jjmtOqwolbO3S2HZayLVunbhXy/xH@ua5ME6Qe0az8ANEbdxE0x/1FUeBS@fask747/ygugr4vKztdA0UbvsXtq3rMPPovMTwJ4cGM9PJOxUKplc/lJR9DgzWi9ObKL1zk06ugxxLy/Zhn9cGALE4ACyf0AajfyZ9tTAE878@yWT2iZkU6up@TLbwU8DVUA5SVKO6EWm1IK8Gmzzwj/7W6moV2yjxsSKyPzT16FlZG7dF@CiXVKoE5NOVbY5gZDN4OQwow9VsEtGEx6gYan5DLzJStSGQtU/Ww1F2rx4dvBs//hk9@T5cSPTuvLPXgeVsG3ILbDw8FG2J0LdfbSBIMVtfdOZfwuyo49o4ESJF9SL4Yd5lqtWW6raolLiDqbZvLBtRaHj54p0BeWTRJ4bhSI7AC8OO6gxtY9veaDCT4LTgXZoIg5apDyhzSossyrjsQ5Cwabth1//jhWF4nfOKvilM8zYN88MhDhwnJ6fo2ewu68gx0e7B0@eH@2zoIALojk3e5NhrZzn1ru5SQxop75J@/FqLO4niUNb1WrxR3FATFyOswoZDCDL2UDnEC3ADpoa8FNvscQmwQcMxsNGUf7zN5SruIxby5MQNx4UKg7ZAskToWxsbLATIBL28Ojg0/0jhuXff0jeiCIEwU7wtPKf/bjHvz0RWBMKvvHmjmgEJ2ssQtRiQXCMf2FpAHFOXXe8/ktv9K0HOs8ffmQi/EqOINA3SIBuz8kQ4DUjcUmy28S/TOfb8AsyIhIK7NXjKgba43M9dmZ6JloTwDL00TzeMrHjxicyCSmzXfyMHX4sT6cPoUDRp/aEm6DyDdHEgNLkkOWk2SYVln82RYxEjG9vALF3DBDumGebICpMKuwVUCKuFFS4tQlJqsdvJAlAV8gloUAQiXjDnp6nNF3l3a/9E2VQZeCegPs7vnuWeQBvv@K/9cH9q9z9QkFCu2l/b1GWaIHQZqZfA16QEP@I@8jX@2xu4WOBODQTGPBVZo6gmc4I6xid58DvErDjBZxE41NoNCA3aDHfsgfPz3BbCTTaWVEUJClUOGQ6V2HM@CbHa8Y7C/lCTlWgkNJZAJCs7Q/w9DYHmExWoJsIZ@a49hKE2O3tbSbirINRK1R5yyqb9ous@DIs6CbEFc6HWLgGgzSQZJECwup@Mhh8UmoSkyL3iqtxZFw9B0YlCsfRC99tHxEiSwCyOI4MNN8@ww89TmAs9o3QdvDTiJEvsWz6gCQVxiRyJUXBt4nxiTMB8oFOuvjWEreJgZt8@QiI1h09/vlTsv2K9Cjf7FmLo9zBJ1/8viYjD@Cgspnrg2m0bcXPEMQxgqiIq8i38YI1J027pXDaZECmP1xBzDa4f1kZrKFZXu/dm5Y/E9ftdiKy2P1j28HplUdQGZbQFC2rqIXkokq53Moq@TXys4HqoHmhS8gO2BSwjK5hvnLG3u7e/sFXDp8d37BuSTHj16MB369vp5qSnG60Qkc8Wq3lJnnwSDl@@uBR0BCLQhci3BgYv18T9baaLGZNEeTiFM71qq0q4fXarS/xZ/yc/vXyZrXbikaJbpRDzXxAvrQTXnpE59muZ66VVmErn7@tSAt4SgT0Hj@MfKOoieTFVaO1XW/asfhNSljREV7E5C3sBOBqelubChL7zcphxcIPE5/gJ9@8aF/Mru6L4mYWjaehLYSJc7owL@d7RAIi9Q2yARYpyEoQdW3vO@Qy@sIIosY/nMytrkVtSkUKXMjchvEIqJPgG8zIRRYmXH3rpUNQyy2zIwS2vLgV08DYYmjAlNvhSiQF/0MgPOOE/1XmWWUm07a3RBK5HcFKs9sMogbwkgJ0aJTunk1B83zmjLlheNre8NAIXEcOsN@HUz4dYrCvTEcQr0@PI4OWmoBzS5AYMBkPi8plKeASvj3UWQotzkJ@DbSK6ldcHvXyiVlSHhqznjkA3p5IpoGjfaSqLRbaTMVKk41UOy5Smy1a4dau@DEeMY@i/YMM584WBdAbumzaPWOWiJ/Hk5UW5I/@8fPPzuJJcRUtkQFf36Jt77ol37D4RfV2TqJP/N4ZmMldxS3K5ZtcAvyuA@YW5YKvUpXL8tAT6CuDNZTcjyfuE3CCGJHoj/QxS0xtbo1PZvSaaCbsNJkpk@rc0qfNUilSqOBBATKjlH1y8fE7odtzllBq@CFK8PXsHj7emGPWUGW5BW7KJMk28WtxeyBxoX3KpAA6MCSpENgakhCoGVAi3klkTuCQBsMhLjzIpuGKYPp4Fs3IO4gTqjWr32ORr/8tS45iuVzxG3SZK5YZUN9NdigrAPYGnwvkesCub6gHcAbqryzEFoz8JseLUb4xXpDHvoUfKE4sYp03MPzDANbCdm536OIvsW9DXwH5oFJ5fvKoXUoqIgstBQ1cs4crRtzAfKji@Z8Egm6qLEWNV7lG9zEmQ5uMbW6KCE0DPqIOI15jqbEoGq5/a35Bm6p6K9X7Cf1WgJg5HAD8E5XtABza0QymklaErWb2P/sZfs1eTGyq6mnbPUvF85kq3NRqnuXZR5tNSdpsZGr3N3XQoiavZ03QyZWt3MMzY9jvHQyUpiiyLMspytbFxUX80dYz80WeFaSeqRVez@ZX2UL29ewqq5Zen47VQkN@PWuJpVr6tMWePfv8bfttUpydzV@LzYQW2zu8FNUcqvyxSpld7BSysdMyqJ@QL2On7A1cp32G/@R@04u4dXR3@qDCxkUWazbxU/RiUVSURrwF/6Tuv4SLK/6NulyXd1pv3yYbuj6ZzZlpmmOv14OfMwQJUkseM9CX7wGn5wkU1qQnaVB4jWb9m/MJecZmu8ZgMN3X6xoetpXvt6tzc/po8vTrnwXXc7zeHEWSvfE/T5tKJSSpsWKeotLW8zH80O2f/WTjKn3xrL39Z98cKcYGPg7x8Z2rp@g@VvMfbWx89OBBLpfWNI27n3392S/u7u7mHqbzzxr5nZyU2dj@0z/Z2NC0bU3ZaHme2oo3Tk8/F7VMTpT/7Efx9rNnX/O8evb//Mbbuoq3ItzOWBH4BFxZpoIT7yX4qShjve8VexMDKldjc/prxwL/iw2m1neK/@V7h69jk1hdUz5z4TmJvY4VSjHuBAe8ZYO3s1g9to3RClexuVKr1cBZ/C//FtLXvwJwMGS@Dbd6PoBVmMfqUo2SXMbqBXComgb5/t/f@EakhJxN1EiMC677rAGXmCtq4k4Lri26tgW0wChlFCWIZ0@GE8Nhaumeeg9fTHiBh22gKXtj0ozhp77Z4X3GjhqpVKoltyW45Bc0SaSoqtZU1XvADqSPtmo1aYtxG5PZbP4e2slO0pTWwIER07j32T/EFVvlWf25wR0JscLG/ZcP63WoU7ae3aqn6PI7EvWpYkl0nPsiS7OXcVBBGq2XTxg3jFsXMyVNTKfT99v0PkNcSbOQkvDi91gs9MEuy677LSWBKL5v7MPjxfbx@vP/7c@//@ffo7/v0@8/oIlKu2f2lS2IdAZdog7X/UqlW6@LdVe8aOJ7HegoUylVSkr7qpnYAg7UOmJq5uPLeD4bP@af4VYZayYpNVyUbd3PHt/rsYV3nfvUo35@AI9MHsyvBTmWsEbuEGs34sHQ6m/mlRpn9ZaEAlFNaqiFfEviqerBVWaN@9BMolYsi626ltcO2f32jF9suOkxJwaaYSHAo1/e@qJu9TBk8VaPesXqQbL6Is6HxgvLK8QaDaVl0IAQ@LH7G5WNUqVQ0ZR2ff0FpBl9paiGYTzzYmex8OKYjS0QGgtJ87pf0BThCwsomH1IPJCM3of5UitlC6pY9V1am4lVIBItK2mDtphRxbC34fw@XBvwR/9wha943yAf35ui3Lw2WEXd0rJK/qPCvobj6x1XtKwCjBOs2@l03nQ7IHXoekfv6upEn@ozfa5POtPOrDPpTrsMu8zyjH7WyTslZ8Y4AcpSLJtXN2P3iKjfNjbYEedCLZYKrmbqzuu5LLd9Jzkc/EmSM4sJsX@Aq65qKtuC8SkDNxDKyAk6M/6pqsBiIGhdtN5uNd5uQQetp7aJObbqkl9KeMjt@62UdHXVAHe16v9v10NnlS7ugsq1rlKp7Rd1kD5e1BspAPnCBylLjIDK7Xprm0LCzPzc/ODtFsgvUmq7sV1z9ugnUweR4jknXnDutwDw9lJh799PyeC6DwDqm9Afk6nUpiRt4NjY8McKiNyqp4JaYRkSIC1cXPycP1D0oBdfbV/VrxrbV1fb2/C/Tfcr/wm@V9s3/umxuNbEWYS3kLU0G0q9qTR9ZtGCd1mpo4@sNMFRhyfEa2S1UquBDrjk1n@b/3J6cQ99sMgtGUotxLbYVgwNJmZjW0Ls5bsv/hf8Nd998fsoLzL4MypC7AK7tbKF2maZK51wY/ZTmz3llw1u/AWv6IMeT@voafObjQtSivJSZhU@559QS4WkjANw2@m30QaDzF5C1Bu8j4laqSC2U@pcY7FtsVAkdvcLN654PP6PXmrlYpxP1KARgZee5z2NlHJRTohc1TKqpF7WuZ18/kmTX1h1/aNfWHcJscsyMyqAn67HOGaEGBBSTFEkCUas@vYIt5njWomEaulZ7XPp@a6E8yj6hFbCunyOoHawXyuX63yZZ/MZdZuth1twV@F/fwPqwZp9iNvs17ojkICb/Wxea6JV9ZjUeY1/T97gHzvp4t/Ra/xjJ2/w72iCf@xpB/9OXuPfbgf/Tkb49@A1/j19g3/PB/jX/FI2q1bFzQtCTUotq1ebM5FQVI3t1JtfmrjzimXYDbPX8j8YlM2VWTLW/JIxw8/GV7hnP/7T737zm/FaLS7F6TMsOdVxmZqsAvahRl68ej8uxGpsU91UM1amm1E7agccJsu4LDPMDNUeKCptlWUMlpln5iwzctQeuAz4y4DLzPRZZsAydsaGiBAKrkk7M0FXHx4D@OsDIBf@TNw12VEzXQYZWSi00RccETy4LttNocHiTHxpgK4pq3JGLpgt/O5NQ3z5sqlstbRyiclIVHK78bIZb4lNEW2ha@Uc68yNjeZLEYbmjMiJD31YzPNAga3GlGZT4WgCDBAWr67a7f1PHrbbCg5DzafO4eL/8HAUfb31f3ToPD10Rg78Hx4eQtcx6qn7KWDQ9@/XgGH7j51YvbrTrBDbD1h/TNneadazEroLKeDmGvqlPvBaQIRnfaMpxM8TqHuco/pR/ey8elYl93nwCo52dREhiMYd/hOucxjiAnXkHK6zc3TQGzrPP2uGLu5QPjsHr88Y6F3hPyh40df/Cv/mf1v/T5@zJEs0WsnExdV2gq4k/iWTF1cXV/69nkwk/JfENvyhB7xjkourOjop0gW4GolkK3l1xf3gnkhuc4B1yGa7TmkX8WBYiIVZUrb8lviv@4Ss/asZr4Lcy3XrfIb6UUysMn2xr6bZnGUyyWon@MwDrhLrl7R5IVmlb/xtdhpq609/RJ/y2ElSpHyuWlW3GH/Rclq1mgveiqVqtRS8bCYS5ZtXPbOjFkD/yOWSyWoVXnYCsBl4hbQN9jbFaqwJ99a9ezyTknZ5GcDM5gqpjJrB1EFOecjW8PSuz3AvDg7pKxjAavIx/PwMZyWJDH1DB7/TFhcr4r17Cf/77zu7yXv3tHLm8jL0GY/BS13yard7pttuo3/28lJsi7QPppyH90zp8lLNlFNqPOm4iU/wA3@QVUJS2UdanXItAxvXckUI9guQ394u5Or1Qg58CqV4EtfUG1j8FpQ3LsarYuyC6qCWipwDilX0ju4Pgr6MgwK7uIpRg7JcPpkARpoEGfAqhn8u8lw@3OTzScDMlchjquUyj5pkuUKilCr7f7UN0MpByOF/KKllU7mt4tZ9kHnxz5utupAnVy@MmnpVuzAqOKt@Ve36n0pGSxLGvXvZMqColKk2hXb74e7JbrtdE0URBSW4oSdxdwENbLjxBtU8X25xjFSq96mZ1VKeQXvyOFIcRghWAqQr2lZeLSGSBLOPhmIAJQLXljbYhqDRE29CmWNuAzxBnYHMe3CxHuuwAV5sgMobM5lFF7MYD6d7txtGcvjlh4avlJb0u8DHCC/B74VZTqIwiD97sru3f5LWtiUW0x7t7qW14@cPYiq@5hfvFJzF96P93YeHzyHBsyf7u8f7Hx98uv/8Gfh77HxxBUzfvy@eUdeK93P2mfDKfaMbhm5MDaN9Pp2ev2avTLNtQmNaU6iUM3CZZ7ShLmN9Ua8q/Lqmp796pbtjuti7H3773Q//u3e/8913v/Ptd7/z/Z9@8f1vw@/H8Psuf37335TzeP/pF//sd9/99u@A53@A3x/B7yc//eI3vsF/9P7H8PtPEb8/9n@RePwnAKxf@ekX3/vRT7/41R/A71/6vx/c/P3aT1b/vv@t9T9M973fvT3Od/8t/H6Pwwrifve3uR8@b8T/bR7vV3/w7l/8O/7/p/4fOn/n3b/4Y7z5L//0B3/6n959899rWulP//W7b33v3be@@e5b33n3rX@svfuNf61morfffff9P/irP/y9v/rD/5H@f0z333uf/3c/@Kd/8b/@xf/@F3/o/34Cv38Hrp/8xb@HrvK3f/BD/P/eH/ztH/0Q///nf/W3f/Drf/sr/xM5fpM7/p9/@W/4/a9/7T/@zW99569@8o2/@fWf/M1v/sFf/R@/@n/9xn/86//@9//6n3wTPX/zJ3/1R7/yl9/89l9@65//5Te/WHP/9q33L97D/4t/AJ/3L@f7wHmfen2ozxc/V3n@PthY5AJ0AtT9y@9@45eAwP8FY@@@/WM8gwW/Nf8/1lSK82P@9v8Bh3azzhiSARf8fv3dt7@LKPofAEXwH@LrO@HLUgh/@c7iBdD6WysS/fJPv/jnP6K3mFGp06oNjt0lrZTaAv1mq1z2x29/QQeS/NIytBCAn9N3kEMthX0Hedu7H37j3Y/@8bsf/ua7H/4KDt5SrpzeTUvqHathEDH/HvEwYuF94mHEzzH/FE2xSanP4Y197gd@/vnnQvtSwcN@9y/B93Py4hfjQXgY0A8KwtAfTweySxZ1@86M79z0fcOcGWu8fNnC9Vbww9xTJHtsBaJRPstmKb9gM8aXddAfIs22yDnDO/li8EzA2@J/4ZwJLDXzp3vhmVo4yeGn87PgTiEP2aRm4WISyWqMS0db3IfWiSnfXJlhDWaz1AyUYHBADikIegDieK2WwoQ1Xh545UWrlxgVJZWqQb0xNU@TbpcQxOwBQYGUtdQRa2/VZjxhCuHVA3SkBPQ6ElVNTJVqDyHD2uwhQ1gInMC@fFmrl2qzOoJ7y/GRmqUeUJkQWC01q7@F9xrBhHRC7OFbKEqplkrVS5ghVpI3T7rNGylPlaO6p1jKbwN44nb/nfuMfSSqJZEvEmwgwnhsvKcWsTEiRIfwZmrLrw79B076bRHCNygrPxfGw3dINt3h4ipGALiSJMsygx@uv@@w@xA846BSlC08UhxCiiiCKCD0YDg/lBJS1L4peoH8Y7WtD74QGFZmc3NTiNXFrHgoE@oUhbmnFTr7gNsBUb2oMLFQFtHboIMgQVkgfZXy34zjwlqcccDsoxT/3b@/xT6CatJz4ScwKZV1ck6MQ9lOpUQN4NedlPAC1BIB6JQAXQryrEYLeSkhnWZMrsUwjB0eHvqFII8XNSEFZK5lVXzH5aTpdBqDFLKcltNp/ynTkzxk3yFTqP@UNxG59AVspmm5KmhPVYZeLKrqqKACo@fbt2@hVWh/VeUAlE/mb7XSciUKBA9u88Sy5sGBIS1XFrhmztRCjrEETbHClWRJgSXYVlLgu/J5IYIrEddKpTjFA@zLia1g511BJXLA6dVYHQsaXFwlLOWTQeDeIds7fPp0/5OTcavFBIO@6G20x67TNTwvgWG7nzzkJzK0ciEZazQQ9ElFQwYj7FcyxIwPHh4dHFcYr7TfBAkqWJXWVf1qllUhNh5/th3zdx6J@FE6RzzGe2VRt4RWzkLSWF2IdQ3ULHDBHBXgKqsKT73BA2cGOn1aFNNqATW7JE0qM@EXnSlDk6ncvgr0KTynIW9vEwaE@oVESxfohNYqCPW6v2ePqUL9eP8EEpwcMlXLyEL9czaTMUPpSqhbNcuwB5PhJm5@E5sZMVKnzUYmjX9aNgt3NVdIq/lia2PDupAwzyY12wXuYryC1wsJq/FluJjwZYF9GbzggjxwayLz94UeHFb9zXlonCzBd@iJah66WVLAeWwOThhHrypQ9/JCkBDb@PrXJ6xeB/1aOngkxIBbDFmwP00ye/JQpmbuTV2DQgeM9cxPTfzaoNwzvbGlz6HrADZiV1dXfYB08IhpdY1eeYoe3q@65NMB99VMF2J2pVJ7q@aKgnZaqbzNapoAHsKWghvgNoAAaB/BlsL/qh5kks2WFOBUqijCI5vNCjh3LAgVQ2C0V@RtplaTOA1mcyptFRHwAxb6rKaFlx939tEibjbD42IIBLDBxGWZIKzIw/y3gkBvgDTcHUefS676nTNz714WJzGyuUw4W0E1ZlfQNpvZXBYxLvz/Fx7A4qs52@N6NqNuK2Nw6uDMbSs6ODvgzG8rHXCa4CxvKyY4p/WsmtlWpnWBCdvcPClD6yc1cWLM0Boy9xPrnmH1ZTxbVBMpA03c9s1914OE9V6t53TpW@fVnmziN@fxrDJPkMuJVcdGw3k1NKFBp7tZInkhDGrndKJaMGoDGW2xuLZuCT254/TmsjeZW3hKx3LcWhzEwXgQsIBugByCc1872Wyu0mAteeyMdwQtX0w11AwMIPhTS2ktvWHsFIuVnty1DN3dyVfypXQPDwD5S1w7@UxlIH/@9MnjyWR8ZNCpoJ1cGRKg9TK0M7RTquTzrUZDFFMNyqaFX2rm7Ena2IA@beg9CZ64AOZJWqkFiXumW6vF4ztZVZPUSjZTuhIWiEOcYw3rAiZNYc3SiPcLnwNUbMcGZlNJ62nzgrBQ6ff7V1sXqcWLoF9I/A3wcyXp6c5F@FqVIvEqbJqWzEUg@Oh9QPeFv7ZXEbV8Saw2qov3YkGstq6E@yOjZ@p4GKiZubiZqgBMmUONQUZNJlxVXMeZVDpG33GNRcSsWggi8gLdjJATr8LsmhnM8eJmdoVIpNnFTSi5vHgVpgqKJVxdAd45sgHtvu3ZOm2abajlXGsfWBCQz3ZglhajxV68EGJbR59m63Vo6otcUcvlc3ktWyjkixqMN@VcIV@CzpYpZPKaBlBy5VK5eAV0rShvY/TVObZ3EdB7hezuJ/QKNxzZaLHk209M66KUlXg5Esnq1VXsrRD76OhTDQbItVcCBt1PNaley@bL4MqiS8tCgZmgaZKWlbKqpGbx/w6Hhv/vH1@Dfw3vkCqrCSdoTeYTGDZhqLfZE7RKMXHYiYPfJRqwB0Z3TYy9oU47mvdcx/P@HnEe6PYpD3pochOuYdBjHT/O5o3MyXBNjOfjERqiMdx/MAj7ow4UENkhj/AAbq7lOKsiFNnzZ2tq@TQ0mg7I4FbTIfrRwcePTyLPk/3dvcdCgT04/OThtUfej5RnT/YfnYSvRR4aJM2HIH5x/8mT66/@I3f4/Kg/dVz8CY8On@cWt9ALD8wKObiWI4XeBMS/4SsJliBRgCKWLwYOVcBjFvdAOb7nO/OFhTODzs/4aWDTC7f984PhFeEkOCKsM@S0HYN1ub0h1NbJFqAvy6vFsiCMme2cs2KG9RzL0vFL8/0N8BzqeNzRQIHWspASMetzx7V652bP2BCe4snKsopf9cZCCI8ByGjaJTsSIMygZdkefgMel6U61tRg0zFb6wkP9EKnaw6GMAafO0EEoaPrDH4fekF6I3pNbveY8DzI70aIdTO6ADpdSRT3RPGxPtHrVdeoeplK5d499ZkrlsUxDMm6NzD2Z0C17Dn0It2dp8WJLD5i7QGua1jOGDUQb9wAkb2sNVo7Oa1eyuSzpb/@rR//3Z/8ek1tZvYy2ztPn@QrwNhAhmUkpvqirExKjVYu5UvlrFZKl8qlXF4t5PNpVUuDPlgsg0qQUUtqoZQvq@lSrgwySK4Mofly0ReElUDyVbYqANbu4jemt0kvkoegAPFFSPYmoSdZTA/fp0w0II0ooAo6oYPjW2YNhk@mZli2yACizros9ujRXubRI1F8gC@4iWMvI4o9fMmXMpniA1E0KGSvhPKU6PA0JbTWJ074SybzADA85QDQ0L0oDvFlv4CTaaJo4sve7qNHmE8fXzRMD9FOeQh/sYKXIkSz8QXkcwLwOoQG0XZ5Pjkq6D6@YJYY8oiH7EGYKH4cFAdDjng0DuBxUNPdXVE84C@7uxiyR9XO84J@FV926RJFF16A8EVxAI6BC11OFDvgRPIXxS64unMd/PB73mgL3Z7oojjn6EEEieKMYuvdU1FsB/6Yzad@afKI3Qq9qLzW9@mljH@iqAWFxmjZ8CUrirnwJQd1e/z4U3046RkDfs1d/uxCTR8/zurmbLr/qPPxx53BoOPOd/c/PsKgvb3HIIvMp25n0PETdtpwOZBq77Gmn47m1y@o9UG7XdGtlUFfbbdzun0tqD1vG1hCSPUaSuZfA8xo1N6DoL3H7fv6qkVkAtjGnj@CZwevByN4PtA7PCi4KIies05HrCL5K0ozIaC2gMu/2B1PgZPa6ZHedZ0qvs9qLJNGgWXeKGRaVQpgI5D6M9UrDO8n8K7jzE/yYt6Y1TKt2qxW1PgupH5CbM60vCmmN0Y7ajlf2dB3VC2XmlXQdoXTj7O4pO6whHpv6w1LfJLc0UADEJs7O5LYUFs7mlqqFIovtqaimKzgfSdbrLxJZOIZxvCWbBRbO8V8JEWxmNIVrVIsghwGOJnAcN7BCZl2InFu6KfJJJaWpgegClRXNqd6mtV@Ypae1Xi52DxZndXUKrcBzDI3gPXQ4Py0O3FcDnIA4GY7mQquvydEtVwSoQCKkkgmQ6YH2rqw2AD62ddOTk9OPieBr@7PXDxzDeReVf/148d78sFh8Iam4uVHKIc6rryHXGsphAukgdcJaCDyYxhCQZsL/PCMoOtY8j7tmwNhNggIjB/JvtlW@eTxEpzjoXPOc0YTC1Wy/Wd3DYaW9M0e02t1cOk9lqBSMT15ToN3u16vtWsjskIAVQxSfZWRmfkFmAOPlz00/EDJL/DcnB/QrmWuqp3aLDYDOO0ak9SXI6f3Ukt1qz00oP@g9gATV9vw7FSNmuG6jiuCLi1W@zt2bWp7et94Zrho0uTgcBNECTxMl@gzI7nJmvsYew/1lCup7jJ7UbJPpqOELtU7yWUvnJULPRA5ia8Flb6g8524Q@Oq2q@xxAuI@hre3U2W6MkPkju5KuDpAWsnwSvzsv@yzzRWyFVJz0ggLOhKhB@st86StfpX4cFhn1YqUBq/oU8BKmYGgM0eBUDssXlV7dYslpDYjCUJSbnqoNbA5Jd425ZEsSVJjcuWUJekz4Q69NfqPKbXvGmHvr3CMh1VyxSqM/BTi7nqEJpXfzGrurXxFMQDC179yTx@lFWvAlIBdwDmzWXi3S99I7kt5Wvcr0qgLi0QO9pyuzar2mjNEQijlq1BQKqRy6RBg4dbMQ1jvlZIq4V0Np1LS0X0hQE/nU@DJ2g4IF4krITImJjOzDKymlYNNZ3IvDR7L5Pp0wQILYQ0lkxPnH17OmLgA02FtEmv8AT0pLQtCzSvnsP0bYmIFVhGFSsGWB@ysZkeIqgjQ7coRTIpsexWwtpMYJzNk@l4v9GqVPZn469BUEJ6vVNIFTOpN8lkNbGRrHnGa6FeFerIXqjW4w2gXH@ek3nTUQNaGVxqUas0Gh2sYjGTzmayUDuzfTnYFutiK53ZKKjQRFeM2AbjfCM69YcSz8Jv3EbJ2zKg6dSyVhVkmofLljSprOS38hk@F8hTCmOfvSEmWaIpBse2E/F4UYvHk/EqrkJsiP60M/A04mdx4K7xe@qOCMKYWBHLGkZYsEY6mZsJSgfi2JWAMiHLgWJ7IVxdXG3XhS8Jx3jeclt7gX/FF093D/HvS@BVhtfSi6fPD58fPhKYQhs95XasulGVq@0qvEhy/b4QqzAGnLTp25RSNhj70C2kqe36C/5s4tkBgCuQheYGa9HWLsNErY19ivYKdlgc6qC7o4amZVsNrQhjH3DTIKqmqVVco4nh6QS5Do3hXUD5tlN1POr3VTaf6ykpUPXvMTZIbQqEntj1eYDd2u7gaDfYnba7t3q2YHOm4AR1UxBF3M0Wu4jH4lfwF4vzg1WlvPgmOLNTEKunmfK2ELtPZxI1fiaRxcJTibjk6q@WZHMFliwHixlfit@PxeNxXDWoMO9tLHazIPXMaVUsFrJ07K76Rsz5J/DK1PzBibCvvtSA8mK2E3iA4oWTYjAy5vM4DR9TXo69r2ul7NODQ/uh@yhyOulFPYZfuJbwoFW18qK9caoCxWXF7Gk6xu7HaHO@WIZsNe5RjbFTpgaVz7VF8GjH1QovVHPjcsPBpRYWbgB8a3/la4yN49lcnLFmLTar5fyd5Wq9LqnbGlp@K7IKDCl9tSBlLuu809QpoKBByLtf@kFutl2Cdy2jwrum5VNava5uaSwZG7/74vfRiM/F/qe7T1gcJ@j/7k9@pBX/7k/@Fe1hi1/RpL2WLcYgJjrVQjF2cTG@uLiCi4flY60YL1SumAQ3X0BSY3VF1bK2bVdZRdH1rWIqp923q4ofVy2qyZgnxfxtm9lCXkokVAVKtZUtZZIQdunH1DIleAuWrnh0sQBtAxXYPzLzmnp/ewfqt5PNadUNICM1PNrKwr9twyujCvn05SVj8NKt9wYDUyOXorDKW4ltv5W22VtcOHorbbCXtTpuQFDxQGywsLKFBwRxcTFeTylbcQYqGKs3rqpXrRStzICi@sIwtuzmNUpsbuAJkWWvLRv@jC2P/jBR4OHBa/BmbL3yxMRWUlF6PfEmhW8bLF8HgtlSFsd22Vaw3sL/JKmZfPdLv6Fphb/7k1@7bF@2P9dAjS2XC6oW@9nPtqf21DN69Z8BgFsMuASqKEmjaGkFHaEKy7gNSdNPFTrkLmjPUxvFdR4/UGhRhWUg6pgD2@iRQiucoXhGjdvmNgR7CYq2hfYd0iTuk82uZFUQArmYi/PuoJsmGGwLDZ82WknhQvgyBsHoz0AlqApfXoACjxGM90637VlTd0wnbBKUTm2l2T1IAjl8Gc0zbpBdCn/okICHKls3k/Iie4Q1EuXYyPA8NPYIo57wZUjiW4e25mysowkVjGnaMFbJGIXKSQG9BuTdgrwtnqBNvgmqPY@QZrx0PJENIr/wZZBeCAsmCDXM3IYIVWBZXwYEQB0SPmCzxbZZNskuzFSqurAkeYVnAdDWpR6YbxAwGULrobmQIHEV44EXqBr4PVKkC7@FQaaMeAZAOAy@daAGygompzeUE8m@ynuDAlhkyyxBVWP37i1KVauZvSSjGiH8U3OME23UDvbqsgKwQNH7qFcR0wxtdFYD35DsAOMpKi5QncSNc1YjSZmIr1eCAP/vTbRIkdeaigKqWAG/vXiv6ALKIDGinbdhl23XmKoVkywsfBfK3qVC0SH6UHttzj6Stc@DwCso4c9iwdd@gGmdRCcvfbq9br@DgWw/xU@toBU3zgx8uxvcThsyv4NJkDpMBVUxLYrdN13Qq2hPQ2AiMpFVk5hsYVKTykF8XMsx3DSfT@KDUmFsBk8dTR36@WyQiaauAw3qjR2bbCOS7SY8sQAUATzKNyvHiz21z/HTXH7bUOJoiTwyKYeUjyUmW4/0TXNKi5sKOi7o3wFu0swYyKw76jGtzBJEaGT@zg7BJSkRFbgD4jniuGMZIyjSsWHQMTevoigDENmmHbIB@NQEuho@MmEEsj3F/3y8cm6emsoJ2siVnD6ehuMWVWIo5WH34/sXfHt7luOcMss8NficdGLJHo3HQEEBGTsNmF38ALEV3BijZdM4T6KmeSz4FeFR5M5SOpJ2IzFP3nxm1Y1EG1v0ksYb08VPw5/pdgS/dF0Kvmbuzb3AohXZZYJ3OWS5hm/LphZHKxWhkSbBt81VI7NQMq51jBNiTAxsWqFTGLvGGUMdW8AxBphmN7AOg70YavtlGgCo70HPQlOXE7eCNo2gJG4v0YWu5zN4m33EspqAEbnBMd84GMDApq8tQ4cwSIr18CY9aBiZJviRr0DvHPUgDK1p@OSH6QPqRjeZIV2QN9vwweGgQ3nVGO8WwUs@8oK9A@mZqr4BgQUo4YqSbCTEFIBNiUmRgw7TX0/OqV0gXlJhNyGlGULwUQ1QSFTQkeWgLcPIN7QECHige/xDC74hzPPzc5mss05dUzY8/K6U59i6pYwHJkjbjjIxRmP/C74mfrndh7twSfxzcvJ4ON6ZoXRbK9@b86cg9L2av70oEe97cRwcz/CzSYMRWXJDE2oeEdQjkz651k34u504/Wmt9EVAfxWkP6kUv0IgjCGYWXqe7qYBWLrTPU33z3tVP@CMOiQAh1Y0Ak@0mewGLyMvcJnjfhjDmSAfDYM61imtGAMkkU8oL7LmNQxizoNX/31sziCRbZyzXdfV5wkKT2JsJODEnMQeNodhn0LACcMMu@AGfM1ZY95aSj4Lk8OgFu6XcNFMm3BxO1BuzRnDZzx8BuEzHj5bZBpk25i1uEiGXldYHaR6tO4ZxEQw8yDOFbd8vAghyCCPgxZFfhhzvuR3Bb9ujVIH@OZv0I61gDCAJsaAcCOhNF40G82W7RnnW62UMgBiFwkR0OIAutEinJ73Qjdi3zqzxo635GWjUVcYlfxyo1d36FMDpxWsY9hARBgcXyba4RyM/I0dXCDwKwwQUA6DQBQNdicJM1kNrYdTIBBOQ1zgmBes4RemRdKXH@T7gbjEUc8RGwXUigBC/7BKUEwIYUHP4V8RDLjDZ64DcYK4En34bIT24OKtOGDyWlfhvKZKjRQplSQFxQS0o7hau16VIByaonEtKFLNK7/9o8Xf@ODi96FfrC49ESwfMKpCtKvgXkoQIfzuQlhl9VqkXaEEypZuGS6MXPtcPvVHa8hmSwnUDJ4PVsE7NyfdYSLS@N0kbx86sSnaYiUkhXmtBlWc13i35P0iQClHeJjM85PNA0Lw03MGAjAyK5MZfrJZNNmsVuOMg83WJDuPFHJGhZzxJDz2bE0hW34y0J4OguEFm6cF0ilu9hQBnsqHURCDxiLz9DMDl99foa1KXMTw81zwHKICn4ZQxEY667ZW5t6IFDrCtK4BQEK8AaDHP0hcEa4zPFUK30IexVEZ8Cj@5pMB5xVAYMSCq9yecyIkMtKBQeAXUzQOQN8VUw1BVGkiGv8y/CemA8/gp970zCzHVJc9M@lrf/8gni3EbKSDRqQPNZNDhoyazHPbN4QalTlibHcKCg5IdZ1zhyVWCNvgr0z9pErHcjrKSMdtNPiZUu4rj@fJQH/ApRx2f@xM9ImTy1W40mQS2a3Kn@sM5sB28OtGEZvuIOv1HMOz4xNo1K4zsE3PSDM0t3lq@GqH4X9kQojKyb7T8QTB39DF1VgEzekKRd12Gz@c3m4ncJ9kshJu@qZtk0ie8biA@i@4IumBPflAD8cJp/PK6E6Sd8PEDxT4yU7M7mnicOwH4vTrLgMe1gX5H0KHIMEwz1lojmT8HEXpziRBH9YYOiNnAFLf1JMFTH0N/MECNhZIH4@pLGmmo0pbiXymgnpJopvWk37Sr35wUvZVLaEnw/TaMoAlZKSZex3HiFl3RXbttdnxZEF@xx9e3uNoeY9vLy9p4dfLzFXzGg/8sKyziQUEiLgoRvbuYmDVgW/1bhRnqSihN8pVPMF7F7FH29R6WNJdiLrrR5f7QB/p8M2Dt7Dgn67D/@0NGCTff9/m06Hbs@M58JsR7vhM0AfpvGBFNgHRD5LIe25mF5L2w/fMC@Lit0AfoQgBYiwxLhvtNkPHHIPa7YUTyAHgO2ged4bdoHvaLlbjgSvK5J6l2am2voketnuGpc@NXsKPmY7ADWp8BAob8av3qzgyOmJ6Dtf1EjB2JcNQGMYR6TxSZQ3J6OmzZHI9WfEoZkg9NFNOJTxYjz8Mv8GacYqvxmerQQ@Ix2M4HXtm4vTneD6e808DWPxrZD4f5eMPb0m0OnE3QgAPfPRU04tsk7exz6NEWKX3GBHCuPJyldFydwARjTndbMMPQ9HdNYXGjSSqBa0sLH8UZ3WLm7e1eIQqAprki1HvR5J3Ed1701yE1DiwBQvb@7Ah5AZk3EbS7SaiELnPrS3m2Dd4AvrRPJ29ZlRpr2CoYUridBOT1G2SL5ICasYH8MQJp0/hiQAHxqTNCSqoG85p@R/4ZBQy0scRqcX3ASEdoESwyFHuFyMSSwjcEP3iKsyzuzbP7o08u0t5hj1gOctIJKG7lKXfCtg8tzWBZfQna7gzBqHuDI/b2DZctqO7OFtxEf9/u/vatTaSJc3f6CrSEm5UplSSsMFYWNgChK1zMHj4sNuLaXUhlaDaQlKrxIfadj8z82NvYOf/XMLeytzD/NqrOBtvRGZVliQw7j67Z545z2lTqsqMjIyMjIzMjI9woRK6auFqoUICeSFYqNTzJJQX2guVLX6IFioH/PBpofJXekjm1sKXhYqZFigwpJ/88BLvtQjH79ZCZTPvfM2M/E9BZNr1FirxmFKZF/KTKUKkQL9Ja8QVW6@vuzkaBrSwsVLpKnBM5GL7xOcwLv9Xov9LmitOgIOPOON8xIXVoiqnFg1rxZB2aNkwCRZmzOSKXs3re9tshhUXQTOLtMez6zB4UsNzC2lhJIjhK99o0F9CEHKzMhsjZa1k90RHt04cyoOcbp@p57E@0M7z92MqfJI0wrnNdH0zXmkQMoD3wxOVb8NzCh3THGOEO1lnBlog6s8Ld3QKY53GRY@@PUJ81p0uRNgWTBEZJQZryXTS4fhyDo0N@oM0k/BXGPuHdh0@lJNJCe6dqMZSQc/MWz7za90zCAZ78jt3dceqB9RSIggfj0snMsvidYFlMT4lss7SVGXyEQqWzKEZHrQ@cd64Lf3I5UTcuLxW3LYMmbrSJEuutJikyh6iaF36I2k93rzWEVvr@7avpuYNzlryAGDVjFsR@dr/Dv29L/q7UagNESYamKVYz15Kp9XrO1fZCcy7SbPTA4iPrtpyZipHcQsJyWl3YGnmd/HalIoPkw9R8qXRGPqEtm/IFu8JvkG3yb2FwIKWMLxKv/y0RC8/Ld1OqGmNpHvlGaXFQ0sajnQ8xjTp2t24SsdnDTG@8Pm23/3uAR6mB9gePMDjDgwnSC6zfHjZYyuXZG6T2JY3EKnlihJBztel8TAnL0nc89VtfG1LL/aa@1t7uzsfaNF9@vSpo9focYIfZi3OWuN1XCCzTXe8HszYtiy5SO6Ey24cx0fn/eHowcdedkqWiLAmZcCnVgz76TnuaFlmyfOJuUv1pKxFUQ3rUzIN/JRUgqrjY8kONV1HRJBglH/kayBGvSV6u7xbcziNUbPZ8y@CZpOXL5OcWK9iGBpzI@78LfegeBkNOQmv5OC6zmQ4nIXa2lPvX9cO1eHruto@2vyr@rB3pN7Xdg8RyeDt0cZOY1PRf/Xdg7rKpMwhka8QG0qi61bQCpCEVi2VSk8UQ97sD8Yid/Kbjrw/8C/U634rwDXV88i/eHkuP7xeMFqXWnXajo5xhhlyfsqLcAR7C06oSNtYKDdtdlCEE4Kisqe0p73Anvei3w47IZXNYO87CIPI@LSpbkgjSPLWuHW7oiQhdyKbDnFOVFhgXVN1n8rj7obA@GJ/BRKjhCRbbHtKEy7@33dT8LC@/@ZAISjG5t7uVuOwsbd7oLb39unn2w@N3VdEz8bB4X5j4wifuOCbva3GdmOzxi8EgZKnEK3il8todCcKHoozVVqfcPPtDWj441/pU29o8OraZ1fNSC1c9iB9Qr8b/ha0F9YylxHUF7iH8lWBys/X9l@9ozVfBb/ihtNcBbP9QfYo4nye8yX1nFujybJO821NT1da9gplh@8jLsYKKX2CNY5ikednVxngbMTTDgOV3YSNCs6@JdgFz2UDmhp6QLAByhisVBWn4lpYcJ8zyHVqrdXtIzKptCZGhPoHqr40piZrGaaYtpUBULhZNHo4DyqvxS@I7@nFkm52NJQC6nH8QgqoJ/ICqmgDtiNqWZe4HO1dQjyrFXnxy8Vgm6@F1dP4xYbPu9hVjZOMGw@pr@JUhgj90eWEa3LKw0lhOXM5V4m4PJKRdbsyMQJJg0kyUa4S2baNSmZJ2HRw1aDN3iS7NL4SN8BOyO@MIpWvOp46hHFQ0Asl1d1Z1@@JCVRiusO8p1YRZamqPcHDOEUcO64M@syASE@ZxiOut6W1wuC@9ajmxlSLvraR5DStxgTtWwhsTCHwR8AQoEJqp9PilYq9ZwGm39GsnI/6xJE4t/3dLk/s3L5sBakK2mor/0v422@OJrKb2icZO0XGjobot2BIaiVfZXb6Q5rjLFY5qRakYOu8PxiFMob5dA/4xomXOSqNhY1a@7m6nmoNdJhssdfvWY2eEhff0uopMeV9WmWOl7vzWHwl2ZaJ82kRFrs7oOOf9q8C6@7MxSXSdYDjF1KE@a4ch5/jEWMi@mcmkR2/KyRpXa2ub218LPz@s4tMrSIWJFGyMTrEf8SYaIumB9/zscHiEHqXnmkmw150eYra2gZPS0vMcgOM9oHnIe3rXjbX4m9ibjz9Hk49k@/55ZcvValVgGTS2bWj83wi3Vx1bJp0uc6J0iYgluwkZEnW580bl2HG8volHHkwCggb1IMcwb59In@dFiGmd6eXHZIsOo2wHu4YvqPW2aIiycEOBx17PIo/5Teqi@tOMTEoURY580ZEuwZy2XEssxRer6bAbd0NjuT3/cGt3omdLA/fBW3rTmjfhVth8XZYsixZsO4P9vc7wMri9ofAUt/d2wHLIjkNLeb0mDnd@VxsTXt3iz9PjR3PPQKDtRcnKDFQq7XLHl9Rmzjfeang2GAShejgcKu@v6@ysj@huiT3sGVoazEI2A/U28TaNuyxsPNipSneLMfKk3mTsmiLXabumMwziXeLqNA6iKvpEQuLJJp4J7wRqadXFlYh2PqeBaKhXBq7z0YGRcca8FfaAxKyyaBZHczM7GZOFp8wso3ANd1c0Y1tG362sJa1G8l5h2MbkG0T5J/Bs2T2@L0X/bhi2hEFC7GW0OE2adK03tA@4YAaHlBBz0uP4B3DYoYURvaiYOcM7WD4VUpr2H@eoZiRRAkXXdgS61o51qiJfjxv1Bw2SMQy4MPSU38Ui2b6YEQ8v3luD6iTLHr59BJESibStb60uYKqn3zVSxhTI14nq7FCbs@1ecbm2GB5gtNZDXvt9kIPYQu9MikeJpsiaXtnU4W/T1OySqRaMjSf2RnzkSCvLC8//hbsyV6Y6oU/C1vWkEn5OboY0P4@ARmNIz7eJ85t7Lrme8IAd5BOTOvNhJmoSKrOjDUl1XdejGz8CBc5FyJkEBwfGXAnW3XUzQRus6HLimRD5yJTfbCmcNxRmTVT1P96d3MQyN9s78H3tyeTDYVgOvgVVvlv@sMoSLzyrMgy1it45KffBcNhj4uJP9MFoOTZjelOZzv2thODV@kVPvJ9m92TjvZOErNb15w1cCN8vOgh6TVO99Ymj/cK5TW7q9uNnbp6xMEyO6mzyOww61iy50HYuwsBlsF8LoHlg334HkYV@o9wcA1IIhN78@WZNs43cWOKkNZ8zNmTtFmolq3lydHvRC2/h1gkbvZhpLLuD1SRT2Hre9vOrJP10lqqPiEXDXp5quVmC16Wq9I7HOgCUhqEjCbeWwsWPDWMpSTca876sI/CxVZwI6dnbDnpF8urpZVnGe5dzx25F8fPTtxHrWpW0eLr9y6iy@F1@9NZ//yqo7pq8MvpTWv8269KLT9Rj6mtpR8kYnF5pVrkILFP6d9V9azEnKsRfMHRl5GE2ZPstEotqGQfvvZAOfzAm@YKPCQmuFQ9ujBcCBe7UfXieOWk2quW1i6OeydrcPIbLVZHi@XFPF78QKsoyRi5mT8enWBNtU9dg96VQlxQzoKqXUMUu4bQmzf@MOzv1HZfpU7joADgCEzbevOBuiS8noM1G3xPvF5wndfHZK4Cx2agIGXm2CuoDId7Pk/GcUw7JMxoVFzSZqMb/nfsZOZK3uVg1OcvJgokWEt9Cb9k5owbU4lPFKjIcWhiRcK/gOAkZfK4GJK3Y7GiLpRFXSvDd9KxQByjJovD7MdsFj6FQFT7ch2fZCIv8FvnQAIZ3r9wNfX8Oed7J1aLPD7FgymHP2SHidIJHnEBQn8GfNuAJlhzj9jtI0Pdx@8yHuQNn1GN2E@GDeQzrCniC8y/1Wf2b@L6z4kAQvg50bk8fcSpNS9SJMV3kA8XEGItvfHHNQPcKmVQ5tBZwJb2qglwthRnGqFZTSZ6P3cNcgqt6H@6B4Uy/5rqRlzekeJMEr6n1r8i0JKHlD@t4083qZa3qhVMNVPYIsXcN6mBky7aHr0JaFqN1WbQ7RLSQou5hBx4ZP9e3f5i3H50jDZPYuTle2HqeyH13ZPvglRSyqMFPilUsQtlc5@Tcl9VNinmTrVVVay8eDTSLY9UkqTs2l1lI2/Ub4ZJ4fV4KIUr4w/PUx8K1pefZoy@fHmQqhMzePz9WL5r/l7SIx9jmSr7Mt0@/mb0AAVsPKttTSa41OuF3RcZnRxcfwGbZYmaSkl1TvqozKSqah9MLU5Ig8M5P0/b9WoCZbFsJA7Pmez685dZTysZL/KTaIgX49TEmjFHLCpxm4tMuBt2WKR2@PMDCwTDBKMpM3PXTeWxrjy2wKLUA9OseEFOTXDq2uQUr8Iv8gv@MZM9jZwpl5v9cU4wv5HOi3dzmkAsdB9kZ5MpLU3gLiIvdafuWEWStseTEGcLiV3rFDhuMxAf7A6OwR/EcsIWFEZSTNE9/qIpnRQoG/a9bQjx8Wvmb8VHmVc@6diDbnCjathm@OyFlUk5uI@CaBQhGhUHyokuB4Mubh1Z4btmF2odhH9pGdctCURrZfcyDVj2SHkXT9ohnSp5ag@Qr2EgknyILs/O4EwGD9j@NUQrTlzCkZep9cZyoEFz5vGSuJkHCsE3WAB3wzMbCRk5mT2gdDTwW4GXIR0tIu0nI13thDpVKp@nw28EQc9oSatkMv90GbY@bb7Cfe7Tculx2SLZlb4OLnmPnyQOVkQk82EJcQuXy08yGetuuCV3wwUAdNUOFvp3xJvBVdDrBZkarRhcMCKlNQqGV0Hby2T2g/gSGHDByriZhB92/3LYksMdUrp8YkZ4CUeuXIcRh@Ev1me5Lm7xXZmbwaVVcttMQ30VtkFA43HS6eN2mC8sECZA6IFKF8GIiPLIUWmU@O5Z48K6ywUOoogaiHNi3U3EZOj1R2GLRoZPsjJdAiXXIEljvfYEJtReq@vDOdibhQDcYxIKGATMVdJdOGT0pfl34aB0x8wdu29GpkjSr89zhaZ7MAxJ@iYE5lHhahbuNMCHrxsH6mBv@/B9bb@u6Pnt/t67xlZ9S2184DtuXJRz/F/1em@HpEt8my635nv0Ils7oJpZ/pCp7X5Q9R/f7tcPDtTevmq8ebvTIGgEfr@2e9ioH7iqsbu5c7TFt@8EQe3uHaqdxpvGIRU73HO5VVMtk9RTe9vqTX1/8zX9rG00dhqHH7jF7cbhLhrDrX5Nva3tHzY2j3Zq@@rt0f7bvYO6QscyW42DzZ1a4019y6P2qU1Vf1ffPVQHr2s7OxMd3Xu/W99XbCRg9XKjTljWNmgLi5a4n1uN/frmITqUPG0S8QjBHVcdvK1vNvBQ/7FO3antf3A10IP6Px1RIfqotmpvaq@oc5n8N6hC47J5tF9HBCVQ4uBo4@CwcXh0WFev9va2mNYH9f13jc36wZrK7OwdMMGODuquQiJHbppgELXoOz1vHB00mG6N3UNaM47ewt7BoUF@T4QhLGtUdYsJDDMI9JaItLf/AVBBBx4AV71/Xaf3@6ApU6sGKsCiYvPQLkYNEhEP7W6q3fqrncar@u5mHZ/3AOZ946Du0IA1DlCgAYOMD8Q61OgR9xrjRHjJIzFrxnCuy8OpGtuqtvWuAcx1aeKAg4bmFibb5mtNcw8Rgq1DlLCPMwP/wj5Y6Uy/ugoQE3P6RGb2GU0cMWlzb6tOK7IOdpVNPhzRqrM6EUrJ/kYrTfyRfqZC1rSD08uzZtjr9OFjGleTg4@L6MxFeiIHuV0@Zu7I0qXPV7hCLtdsvqs1aaN70Gw67n1qptD4Vg19DH5XKUf3EbkfsPPGwU@lInR/niLU@g/6opMN9XABgZJC/R/E9M2/CBxVLLYDXQ3O@wBsjo4iuTY5x1UKiUZ2dkRSmqRJPpng36FmB66YN@C9VhPnpLCM5EL9iP7pfUl@yOJgvSDpLMddxSI2sYxG@FtgmpFGOCQC/6MjEoQdbtKLguDTWb5kN4c9v3fW77fzjmPqcNkR7QPP8s43qp8GZxPVC5P1GVm@dtZpEyKz72YVJr5/1iRTely8Ifcsj3@aI/7jGGwk5gNOTbkpPqzWh5b5H6Q6LJJcpUNbwL2CBxk635vaj4332M2Vlp6sTbx/Hb@XuQV7QUTPpQXvmOud8J/XJ1KAJhjH4iCShDpCRrFo1TH2JnHhayp4jkLXYRuWP7RWnwe8rhNJSJG99Lt2m1iNh@GNjT3J4Vf7tTcbR9vbJDqB7ZPV5acra5k47NaPrvz9gHY4wC1HHRvQOk56Gn@yZskmKT48U6z44gn7MwMXiyiIuPFm0Pgl4jzEdhtpSyYIMnQ3QoamHkz0sgHokFUcgONBxvDrzJmpGSCf6qqD3lz4N6zi@6QrMQ9oY5bumEftBv8Adjz9zRSPO6QZSLMYh/wlzqXdBcu97LYxFeXNDQfuQREva/hYwrjFNOCjLrafhXct/9K8bY1iJKaMmK887FyTkHgwiYUydhU9mdlvOc6IPgDm6GH05kfNb/T4QQe443B3fjSqjQ6IjNtxTZxTJ4fRutPHGvIJ8nggqJpp6bnCKb@jkeK5p4@T48Ag1mxgVJCUBja@acBrcRyRySbZAvblgqM@C6cieAfgrGmO1b@Jc2d1R0NZM/FD9G8TlUIJrDjIiVDtOm4jY4p8iONYGHKmyPSn6MHw/4E0mQH/Oe04CXpCLSsI4L0oyVCFVrR9ZaKE1@aiwbrdSKhpv/qQgPlqD8x53DF9e3Mj/jVEAj06Y/PiA4c97ORnEABMjoMNe/7GJmnnPm2dXmYdXR33JL3WxSCv9FphloopuIWVE5fVLtfcreCHoxw5a7Ia3KGq6qVs3E551tOWaWIrrx5GWQHnmPgfxUd8ABJPeObSc7FaneSskp5lRg7oUEvWgtOOIyaRWvr11lu7R8oKkZmS/frmyxCKQK8Dn@l@ckKTvhLz3HTERV6J1SFHwUMYc2yTsfjokHWnbIjZDQDnYZsPQ5DzZHSNBaIr0DlUXwJN5R@yoQgaSawOkziDELeOR6TlZfU6xp5PJsGhMfZHPYmgH8iplinhSYAPjaHtLu@pN/6YUO7er9vCYsVHB30XtotoTI4ldH3kd2n1@0NSHX30m3B0w7Hjqff60CHoRZdDHb@Q1rNwqE8kjNJPzUBtkt07LzMSup5Ri8IRvBXaHvMHd@kigIWohCe5KayoPDGv4dF1c@gY3iyWVf558uU50YTDkjIRn6sV9eWLlBKC6pChAVMwjOLNBdtscju4d4in33V/@AlrP1SgXjtox5FJLZB8FiiD1OhxjMfWSLo@6Ed8okFDgROQmBJlOUiLDVVpjX6q2UnbNWWT6JiIXco9@f52YiY11lLUUMK4unVivpUCDSaotKRDg8bBQstLy4zKrA3X11s3YxwtNH1trbIfe7FIqYgSUX1oVEc8idyMnz7gSR/yVx9GmD30BnfcWgUFwtBZca86LecYP9gUvA@DYds@EyVNpu0PcPzGW59@j3nRHB3qsH8tfxQFY9oBtIrhTZFhNPN/6Z/3mpv9rn8W9kOf9mmIO38jEg@PY37EgJ0N@9cRpy7iD22rUHucPEt8GQnDht/xveSaFZorGgWDvG2mMBqOa@cSJoJPzmEEmKRNZf4eTMZIi@s8WU4qZdL@p2yPV3bWbq37uDyrstzoA4AWcOsTFhTiQzpixyTL@XRtqsDpXQUsHE9VQfnOLRZ7KYyfEYn4GiaFsUFmyizB7gR2ZrdifNy@cdscg3CIQEvBVoBEPFGeX7s@MlGTFHkBS4GKKq@WrKpyi3KDOIR4GN9O7qWn/2DsCYE/gX758SxumcUILOI6JtpSJPsVHWWUcGHzwJBlNEtikmLhWdiz3A8568XNJNT05/Ft1GDLH1KKdJi9Ka7EjMzTxgcZ9vJNEjnNsYNFZUEtOBy3AypIbZQv3c6wwbfsZ3ny4xJXTs4gmDY15LyF9G2kahGVkOt3wrzWRlliKn97xiwt3XfUJghYnWVyZuWczmeN5sIeKKGsr7jW6g9JGGcnqKdNPRaiUX@wcE/q3So7ZkZmm0XrluN80xBYmK1Ki@WjNpO2OsbjeC0zic8E06QpxpZmxEPYvvJzzOaTRLypNjHfqs3xN@hwG80Su6l4UYnHuy1zH4viFSx6zUITTynGHUFK1@L3x03qePN2CaJhyvaqyRKjCZHRHMujBWqCTDGV7k8h5j6N@wQ92kQ5tNsm2tnjcytRJ43kTMhT8ykV5BL0ROB2OG2SXBp0YHyBMHGi4cZCKlY4b9wxX@WVC6cIMowPAhBacVBIzqHkBDcZrAk@4uwAnXwT1kJlSCJ6WrctHOKg/zHBOCq/PtzRFg/NcaF8siaQbmJItKvgUndBMv7m9PO4ecNQpkhBU3wGKeIeTcmm8/v36s/2hcoRBKnNn7Wlb8lFZxy1SNjQP/an5g104KQpXTM1o9ITocmigeYC7VLOuoFsV6H9hUPheFg36GlEGwh5ncefRV0D4bxXSjG1UeWmPUYRR5NbZpujCutSJWEo@Q3y66koqi5vXAlAIBhT/WqZICCsKWOPSwEOvWNzXgpRPUZUsVrGtKSXHBU1sfOc8R1E1QWeLFslSrNKPLNhFGYCIcVidpkEEdJZZhdJoNBCNxMXq8TT2f1JSpBCbHhfKE5DoUclTcN45ISAnOS65CQS5bis3JLmYP74ZNlJfYz5m78@K1lfS5NfiT4xhseF8uTX1VLqa6rZpaV01VRNoodjt5r6SKRwbIRjqfDn/seuKXbI89gm1NpkpLQMbZ@NJOS0y6R9m/dLpJ6zU7bRMQw82zPcbL@akmIlFZT97gDsaoGvDBC7/U/31limGkx0rgCOS2ecXfKyIWSNNYulHt3CTtdE2osDFJg9bb@j3h1ub6fCvp6OjaHRRTBcLpVKYOJTO/i9sa3GUVLYL6ZLFzuX3W5xcP2X4bvTIsv@IOCUABWzgw5oSGhSRF5/eCaZIYADFUXpgnZkxV7/stOxUzDghhKDR8MmJXU0BMULUBgbvbw75AMgBqkX2J/RQfTvZxXPvmtfFE0NxVxDUW2YBF9lze0ZkQcvOrDPjm@qGBgEs7FmonXLqa5/xgqCzCY8WBy@2PmcmCdnXwfdbt9V75H8GJEC5r5OVtjetiuUpAhuGNm79zLieLSuCq7CruVXjCI2rwOcWZhMngkTFx6x8feDs/rNIJ89/ilLywp1eRHdXER8aldlz7KODhZ/D7DCh4T2vUpf@IN8i@k0WZiWej2DkyfC6HHZnbn3SRVx@ExM0@zbpUHU2eh6HKyBuu6wLmBi2fPwck9uKR4TN/vxptwBDUsCQ@OEmCv3qwFXs3@cWLwadTr3k4qcBkAG9rskomRC@XMCke8AeAbq6Uf0RBTtvxZoWm9PBBQRBQfJOqblDio0USGTediq/nqdr9Vqan6wuKhqtQ16KBRUbaOmtvBiY0Nt0e8N/P6hurS8vCYyd8v5TC83zMuvaoNg8AnnYut8uEU/6VsVfmOw1sYQzxer8@7afLP6fH0tKh7XNuDWT0//@S//8z//9X8Va/rHv@PHBv84/iku5Hlecb71ef6Hr2v4fbx1sjB/ejw/OFk4WwOX/Y2jhvcbo4KfmI96w9NMTlYB6y3bkZp9Nkef0VWVyRd44Q8/kXSpqFwrKub020gyR7GMzbUC630AP8pT2sKbpAOTW3lCIkdAxziOp9FpBTDAo/WGKEm4wA5U6svdijm4RziYuEB8q5LTkXhYZ70K4NOSRFKALy6tWIWwFwU9nIBfsc4r3ctkfPobjpqaf4s/vYnONvo36tHHvHpUUo9c9Sib5T/llWf01pkvhvDOlWK0HchmXfqSXC3AzFBFISt6vH/gXDsT5M5k5jllDyCZMBVcWLzg3Hj3x84yknAtOsvMIfenkiMSvmRCldzn@d5XGpbPVOJrNuVqw4pCU@9iuDHrRiUeX6hAfiSGAEnLF0KQSp@axE0feyTjqWje6LHOcDYhBgyy7r/a5nmPF7QWzfe0zXNqL4U0R2w@L2@xNq6JMzSjjS/SfoIAX6jIdrLEnoQLuYWMWHlbveRuihe23T/NfGLrMA5GxjZdKv2uLCYQa26bcPM97deiDbnlekVlw/h6xWoqO2n7rTJWlYvL7igcaHcFbh0T6nPc2leZSRhRBiRwJGZ/ZXqG8UGBiRQ1MSySLGus2n10XWZCT7um0wA7ntwcWUQo/pSnuf1lYm47RfYSMewgPMBIxaZ8HT/sRjrqypCJfeYPT5Ed0O9wQrWR3JvxeR5yuE5g3O/ESHsMmU3Ok/lMXckNhv7Zhe@q3G7/cOiPG7RskeYzankO9RAhmIAEJp9uelb3DMLSIz0kTJG4K2w5hOQF3bFOjyZjm419TjCkZirosCuYBCl2YkoGX1JjNUHHhKu/YxBslKeEd3wbqUUsS15YGmlIWdtthqfZ1NTJmBbsuRNPnGxGUI1npuEFXekSC@0FX/ySJO8iRoBuO6u9ALUrwsoztI/V6Szo@anFadDNGEf/4pqSdRHzmVNRijVSRkN5Wk4y3gEr0iN/SkeBkLXJhDPKzOXzcx8jnc4tZ68jHOQ7tsUv@iqME9BxAjP2DFFHvVCE5cQKleTA8FSDLf8JQqfrnxF@42t/DFb8mMu/eFB0jn/62Dt5lP/Y@/LxN4cx0SLZrLIFldOX2UZi6blCK2PRTf00VmmRCTX4sZcu8LGnxIfFIgEhUswf/1Q8@VIkhD7mHOdR8WNOCJIaMmBSvLu9IsAXp9DMpbEo5jJzziPHDH7@RdlRtLbyX4yhvHDkL2FhNpV8TE/7nGGHQLGf7q@X4nISFVeXSk@Wyk9oJ3QW3BSGwSXW20J0eRrckCoRYTtLS8/H31LckCLE15vIX6OXN9RPSWsivieRdlLSIlRPc24nE7MV1fGEJ6g8UZnDpcLFxYnL@Lh8xIbfVcRypizHghLTQYv78lg/o/4F2vEjyLVJ7xDhSFgZiI0IH6EWANkkX7mNQx0zXRbYz8lTm4jdykBoeIs5a7Xo9XsFraw53sIalGh4zXRXS6ulyTk6NUVTM3ReK1MLD1R5/cXT//i3vV9zo9z6UvH9kP6Ocr/mVlZz8kgP9Oux@XWVW889R7GVr7lxkfbA9Pj0P/431V//C8HBl/Fz@md92cBaGefWC1Wu8iW3vkIP5aUlavf//PM/Ux/mZceGXKzzTVcxYmuGIpt@j3mXvqsGeinb0oVErLBjFmCIhSHtzekHDKNullZLfEyX01YVV4GOfGXsUfQSz4ZZIzYVkpMMY09BmpFUqKKBgoA0JhQdZdluGLMNMG@Cpvr5obcS0Q7gZ23OETcZm248jGAyNC/bIhrAvLRI@3l5WC@9yMbmHZWssSlZMyoktnZa1q4@XiN2eNsPRmErbSVhputFy78OTj3woRe0L2lP1Yu6/V@GxStiyYvy0mqxg8P9IttxFwcMqTAYe7@RIqiTAdHGkI1OXTWkEehfIISXy9mCSKHfju@kTD5J0rIHQUvOsNI5iamI@Pi5cj2M7niJKp3nf0mBR@ZMnQjSypX2sUc19/YrKrsYF5RyvOd1gM1bNo7VITAKYg07YNnkZbgPOB00/fFqwzN2QuJaiLouRTy/3W76@ls@M5c1qdLczNx50B1Usx0J747Yqbgx0fQXNfNWKIUQJwiFAgs6wLoIRj5t0atZfoP9eNICwqTou9Y4VFxC1o4uq3f17SpnXbmj6Wtp@ppGFFpC0k7MM1Y0NmUXE9lSxVHlMGjiSm1mw9RaZJI2Dz3@AwwiGZZGB24JujvsAUlUS7qjrcrsYXN5L0w8ch2Iz54cLUrm6kwucX50TQnxoIbuhHY9aYwEBKLgVmChTL8PxAOiatKMhr2MxPOb@Gzie2gw3Ic9hBK1w9ZJ8FFZlnpXyH0TjtiXUhEJdFxZ2wY7I6tHDDoOsRWnoM3i4CXrgKU6Fd5scUEzHBVOA21CQmWzck513FJxetmOzl4riSLoRbZUXnr8ZHnl6eozZDmb072dDQaVPOwCBuc@wWCNOk@bbLyvVrMLWXmFFNTTTQL6LLC4gINZ17XjmLDP186DarmkgZWyDOua02hIdX1cySATiMPAw4pAe5T8MJvPv6gco2MnH9vOF/qP@NvEB2SGM@FofSG9NQ5vk8hUmQsJOFBlwcxBcfKPEUHF0V/sskG/s49oEwFsXYXtqaEdRIAYnQ/7l2fnNnd4OrTVIU0YIjjHpcYO6lUwSgKMWVhBF9UHDg3L@6Jq4B1P9wBGuVgSoPMJcJpmOm6lry1NMTsWaBFCZE14rOIK0TIdtdmZubPXV/XdrUnEcnYaOobr2ZatpNxxJDMEkEGuXqu7h0RdHe2CXUm1THJTUZVZwJVQrszu8D58pVtIRG1Rxchq1htG@bvIUmZeTEKbJlVpHIHXDJjl0rdJafxaTS9AECMI9WlSLMTc@D7HJlmCkz3ImKfg5WzFshF9E0YRB5jTjWUdbVHKhTirwFzmFoA4tyllpSOlCkaUH@uceFlGG8kcxSsaRwPaDDneqQYzS3KaCba6jSQANrKOG1qg/43dTVdt1emf7fdbLhTljdpf0e84xfPt@JY1vuWKamybIbCjxbLNLWymfoWLEjFLSQeMTRCE8O1IVsQgiRpQb2xr2sukPk7N7ZOEK8CuvlbCzemoniQI9MJnIHN68x6H4mB3HX5XkcOraUkTh1TR00KOuO6e2BZN5pJWY0hCynuAWJoEEQdqSbh9LmF4sUBnzdvXexfD2I3t2TydYlnZUJHavl0ksqd59lbK3MUWS5otlioYx7v4gvn2Tt44DTp97YsWM8c3eOPBH@ONwv2Zo/Dfgjnq/xjueKy543EFske4Iw4bzh6dnIa9P4NjTse8Bjfb4VmI86GO9ROdKLkWABZ4wBA@pPSxXELfbhEnKj/7w@LkegQjoaVlOAb8oc4/0Z1/UoHM5cet4L9q5wt/584v684vV7DWzBh5rdpZ4db/Pj1OVMJ8@sXM4YW6K8WcP9rTFd3TlQpW0xnD/P@9p4X/Rz19qnv6tIKICXLhIOHr7@Zm0URqB5uNRmJu4WV00K488tjP5koHe692NUubh073MjqvQltXfxj/VY3/KqQRPyENHe4iYtvQeC8v21NxlhfNkk85FJyspCfSXxMZ3eqvXrCS/YheoERI88HWUG9USCF35WNy2@Ql@mMifePF5744i2zXyTJxcW5toGVHWHaSKS6ar06SubQSrytbHANZbR7u7yz@DyHDhf9Je6ER8hja66DbNSuJvQU7jKNO6c5Y3QHsA73nSLGKJicjO9Le3jG7zN0u1TiwxcS6OHuTIFdtuP@jvdQF9A0rKzeOjIg2nq5vdlUwzTXbC3lDfZdCs7use/yHuPSZ5tJnFbWvNwa3kcrXB36aF5N92tLy8l1rgNTy8AcTsORS@Ttm1f8F)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/12rjo)

[Available online here](https://purkka.codes/jsfunge-98/befunge98.html). Note that non-ASCII chars are handled
differently depending on how the code is entered. If Open... button is used every UTF-8 byte becomes a cell,
but if code is pasted into edit field chars on BMP get one cell, chars beyond BMP become 2 cells.
This program:

```
v
    >1.@
  >2.@
```

prints 1 when Open... button is used, if code is pasted it prints 2.
I don't use this behavior, the polyglot prints 367 either way.
I call it [like this](https://tio.run/##lZBBT8MwDIXv/RVWL03F2mqTkDqVgQQCiROHHRmHLHNKRnBLnG5MiN9eslWDCXHhlMj25@f31nIjWTnT@oyaFfa9ZpiBw7fOOBSJ5iStItxIKzTnDuXqzlic70iJZM26oxqzaVks8fCdlhlSbQjzdeDOkn@y2oTXtc6Q55MNkdEgWtcoZM6lqze5DSr@GS5mMEnhA1RD3FjMbVOLmFtURu9ABy2SrxinFRxhfDdejEPhM4qKAhgR/jokaFdgpTc0BsNwP3/IyvJ8mo0jFSIK8fy2c3rc4@RpBMlAJ2mYa61UKIqFW9BVUY8gXlC8dzUkFbYRbuF60L491MReZgTUWbsPcEi06Xzb@Rtp7VKql4CxdzC7/PbGfhVG8q0zHkXo/ZCuI5FWff8F)
from nodejs (it matches behavior of Open... button).

JSFunge-98/PyFunge are separated with the same method as RcFunge-98/cfunge in the previous answer:

```
>0k;"763",,,@;z"482",,,@
```

Answer (score 1):

## 368. Befunge-98 ([Clostridium](https://github.com/palfrey/clostridium)), 16190 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1\0C0<?ML 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'@,,,"285"z;@,,,"366";k09<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"763",,,@;z"482",,,@       @,,,"368"z;@,,,"364";k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk5mnjx58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6FGpsGbNr2asq@9w03N71FBr77OTRo@u@WfY1ybHZo5tFUnNsdzpxDibX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7HlgAZE4Mq5QpZa4HFaE9jYnZXcoHAh6ZLrSu7rci6@o2tBa25RYzRuPJnEm8/XXLCtvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZuToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12aszPHRea3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikqAcABCvxGRocDgjfQ6NbE@AOJjOPCiGZQTQkkIM4j80OtMBc6aT8XTCoGw909M7FgDtzFnP6OtTa5JmHQgDJJP/@dCwfWIGcDKAOHF4qV5NqWjGgub1Xo9lgI6hHKcGMwFrVKwKy2bBnzkuYA1iBSXygRFd8zoaM2gzaKK@U2H5TAbC90MfLK1ueY5fmOWiYaANfZXaDOE@c52Bq48AGz2DcPrZwTPmdR0X3uCHcXl/ug1MV5@w7W0W3//0YZzVw2aR3Y4QNlGNXUATxIJAdqZbU6CQaEs40D5umFrAJotvxCssDmjRMiyXYznotiWm5QFJaqYMDuj/WlaFX4FpJZZToQfl42nMp@/qA9MyOJQBQiki4Wt5psE9k2NZtcRjDhyrz6N1KbMiy5ZYociKeVaEe5mVNcgNQeeYWs7DrwA/gFaGoqjwy@Y4oAXdA50ire2xvj4yrbkPncB3WV5lRYAI5VUBslYCCPDMZvGXhR8Va/mKwp4MAdtD/QzAS5Z5itzICBkSNqECD2VrSyGOiCyXZ@8NMXtAHSAtX2JFyL4AmMhBEQCzWgmyz2d4RbyhYVl@sqGHyai0xQz8oORFwEMJsJ8BXGYQmUX4wTvwOw0YmwZcTAPGpAEz0TRwZzELiFeAsAI0ZcHH11D3TiEjno/WI@QDRwcwKmIbmZiKSAII0FosC21WYDkghCwSQj7LoPxQlmKBAR8rqayUY6UiA3yWMwzaRoVyIZWowD9VKI@KwKD9VSAAFcqkArZVAKpm80yIIFvNYjikzUJaQI2agzQ5cEPDqQX8QTqgDBWyVCFPTSsviBDKpuWhvvksUadWgNYtQhjgTYOyakBOGpRWK0E4pi0BDktIvMV4miNCRzxAqyC5Ax0CMvJQHoILccGtFbMcf7o1Huod5NY8ZaePSQvYDQqIRkiawerBM4fYhKJkAAz2Aii@BhSQBXRkoWmzuTB7SwUgDQRv9Exi0JYJvEsNMVRME0G@0seTBdrUApVoPJ8MQz@N@znAOE1gfsZA787DQOh96TBw4VvIoq9GvHYBKJNDXw84qzP1rAWQ0JHTKCvjzLQWfiXy6xl6r296w7eLsuYok46hT2zzdJFLPp@OIFWPBBQwYMmrmI3GnZgSDFeDIboWddGKGGfshA20VGRVpeJ1jP7UHhhSuRQpH4VMpu4EBpZFnmXu7ZqDAYzJCzhqmqpJA@XCO08ltLLZiRB6InYxT9eE4fse6w5BoAgDyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4KgugRQGo0AZx62@OWOde10aNRYFzBKeukNzHESurI0caVzKZFYqRGiDMPemlAlZM14t@ZVj2ok4iyeFKwHGGi5ZRkdqGNA@x1EKx10kXRhXHZIaFuwzYQcjYxKQtjzIw6hrARuFRunqOALjeGTQeBrAMScyg0xADDScMxRbaVBcysajgbPjopQKUk7PcF2GcUG09dI0xHrTjme8nqIctShXH8ZsA4b2vm5aYQFoHNEnJADAM@5BfvPlYvddZ0SDzQiHUMtxxmvEFRiwzxHQY@fcWBR9MZ7r47EFUhP4G1xog8Kc6yRvk3AezZUXCBJhOmhwAEhZgbRhukaXcO9XHVJnQS5ZLmKFafV7WYTyICJOZaGzgKjhYRp7alkVkHOMLsvWlZ5xpqAPF7mWRS0sQyCEgSjlg@joICtjyakUIaR7mkzi3UnQsp4zWq4aH18PwqoPTRSMrHN9Dq3Xh6HVmOkjkOgZis3Qc9kIKIa3ILYE6CxYrQPWc@z4JIRy7oIQC5UOa0KCMuJkYo4M0H4cSIItnqNC4@hOJevMgZQJWzmZ1B1ekmuIkoXriOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXcQa5m3aREEgJnko47vAKrmfMHFZs6nDzwV5buxreDI6MOIxFi2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/gPIHTh@I7dyEugPDgqQL2F1CAqIg9JrJXVkglCMBjU4tZrLueMzAHwYlIM9HmRKIoM4rk72BQGsIKkR36rpzNhtDS5gjiDXpOv0@UO8bYzwEEGzUY915F7onNDJSj9BziMF0x8vVXLxtGhDHRqVk79nPs4EBaAeBtY/aKZL8ogLjMVWBUKHbXJi1dcAUVqE7nhNahNgiRd9xZPTvOYZHxOK4p2HXx8w8Y0BdA/pZf8GMRiicA5XapFT0gPP43QvhY4bCyspgVj4VfGzY0HW6QJXQ6aH5sE13WR@U7IgIi3qG3u0a44lPJw6xM9OOyPuHj1DeJ1/JByZ7Q2HzPtu@RjUQNaSciCyL@g8WfeyrITryWl@Tl0jwCFVOzlms@Y3sIcbZtdzFlxhnqQQvxTVlGFOXQOWHmMR0gqwEuaPZHSIvnCC3IXkbeps7vVl98Itm746Y1A/zxtKowHYEWQm9sBzrYUjws24CkscWwqoveWDUJY87QOveaAVkJyyk1Yv6yoouA1O8C@jIsZ0VUAGZIVyMshxCbUHEeIxcQ7dCYqTu4i21ETLsxeQSDmQwho7Hjgs9gzOdOc0kUJNFqMtXwBPhWJGU2YPloRWGjDgO@BMcBSHB2NKBFrCLYU8FzUoHTgFMjCvIwPMcnmOkwNTrCZZfvnNi/ZyYYCy1bQOVM92dcyBQPRieIaM5M10X2OAZDhJ8DAoGE5noFMYEvddDzorooH5/PXMZKXpv2jFn17XwLnrKrzzhTHdZHxVwF4QO6ESJeN@LJ6vkTykjQaLijCcKJeV3ESJSJBmaPNEHnR4GiUfAaI7ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpPgwIRcRmOfgKpwvXSoPiDRjE6hX9NblQ1g@JYkuEvoRyXBAEXGAN0FOQM6IWiZ5XKvo7NL4B4uk2Z7XBUJVBJVzoV5GXYvzMtHBJYlWl@ZZ@G5XXJIkVENa4DRqeY0SCwh8D0xQQlF8FAUf2xFD5L2eBjJNdxzatM8HEtwUSTJLkLhFwaABBXGBOHD7JqTti@u3LsXCC4btRoQG0hTwDZ7yahGG0xYysCpIbJM0oifiTxxjifYNxJJqC9GvuKlAbEJKLVWZxeToQs9jt6vBIgEaBVspOQAsX47f2qeTnvXG9pGT4wkYq8DocnsTsSqAIM/7w2127AaX8IqaL1xxCoSL6Yn0DeIl3yxQUU/mmt4KP7W/KJEWjiBJfBpdSWKeFLfb0HQe/Ou5YsE3AWdnXOjDhT/1J/IChlR2pcJgk57o6dyINgdOBz2bPfkcc3vizxQ6Zh2ZcnDcrq6Rd6bGF0M0j45eHC0e/Tz7RUwLLNTue6hmLlSAYfa6Uwa2FMlJ2uVzSiMBeCH7dthY8LlOKLgBzPJmUVEpXkXBpdZgM7Do69dRwlIQogOygHc@Lsm0vA4IHQJHd0bXhuE2SCVgizDJEFcJh2wAGbowKJjuB6U59n0zRtsvOuFGvv@WDJrqnMAgadyYAfpZAy8JoAFQZ0@HxEpLUihpo0LDQtXNGZQno9Rar5eGBKlIyTz8eGj/aMagfXn1SSKongTkKV0tycDzVtTUMFXxQH2B64uS8mLgqM8TWVdieBudwnBi7Zla@ADANR1ZIdJ1iiomjeEsu9drxv5St2QAuidIFyXK6PyUPdDCxopBw5xXVR5V42iFLAYrEKvlSNWGLo8bHXzeaOYK0eHre4iz14UKC0KwDgQyI0uBJ16EvrICynSF6v94h8/uVFwj4RIUAWkoGSexWTKy7ME1F4kk8U9ZQ80NMcy5M@J44lMTCpKPFgXkLseKZ@R@Pszc5LIJPlTTUJcyH1390B7GET2p6xpJoOUBtTFcWRy@7i@1/WARmzHcgYO24I0XDoMMgSxaW01dweOfaOFdPTEqsZwiRD4L07c6GMYa8w3pDhSqqi6yhcbdds7By6tFrKIJMIQgVIovvxKP9MBXYt6Hx98Yx8GETWfyYTuDF2AgkgaQhe6uhFf8mASZCT75VlZwXC58EZvDwKkyHodVtpndGHC3UXwSk/imLKyMv7KIn3i3MD4K2d@jbTAh5MWOCIoO/j02ZODT/ef7n7RnGj5/NJ7LlMuAOIgvw7IQvKQ4w176xbvmlgtBBeDvuFi9wIuMAUFJVgtmnouMG4Zo8i8AGuohi@0Jj5xhnbcS16vzDmGSq/sLiehp9j5eFQ/ISjaPQuVEZevVuN4jvQznEzGXkVRoJcPpx0ZlFblVdex9IFC6WBgsCxFRdXl4BDnNbxVKaAw3tzgKfjkFogOc5pB1K2RA8oLrXkja2AJDp5mrSxzMARdGBfGDTcphxRMtVF6oCGArqyEdSMGTG@AW/8ZtJPISfurqlbidK1mtJwiBtGWuj/E3egboDolYLQCVCSvvbLmveY9NgcujZCuA4kxeYsmOTyGY4HFQJCkWVPU8wPkELfA@VLkFYSj11OczQUupeQzuaJayCugloGaBjKrhHNu0kifdIfSxJEAnuT0ad4gQoV9r6vbfXnLdwSFBbnvI6hqtvGi2bRbIKA371HZcN25MW811Fayym4m2fLjJ6tAvUvVQ9oNPIB2yQmkSU@2hp/19JvsrKdT7@oxZTIa@2OONGZPd0GQeuMAv@4Z0b6HCZRooLK1FFfByG@VFRNCFiYV8IaYUqBDwUgLpKdguSQQelE8BMoBvhVJwBazGbwefH9HhI@g0o10bzpxj9ZIUK7B2VJvDEikyeYucmkP5wcnMDqGlI9cGhoXmTQ7N@I4j657fLYSEvlr/EF60NVCCDQrH85I2@GuBiACSkXqOXAOoCucNh0uZhlR6QdKgwypTDj5ABKETasHA@AzkJhXZJdXhOdEPstVOrWdcxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17rNXrRuED2r8TgAjSoX4eu0KN4xunyWlSemWoASqLORMXJwKgGkK2IFBlVB5wvqqAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfY/T3gYl2DzxdJI1SigKT2WXziKrvSNxRdegPUfItshZWPNLHf6CcBApa3N9AsiT8DStKJM6JIn9N8CwY@CMRdAVcMocZAYaJec8aGfV3n4xphIlmlbQjxOF8EuohvbGzEK/F6PA2uHXBto2sHXSlw7ZBLIhfGk9FFKdLkwtAGpUC/VvyqEUCeJVtIAzOUHN6Y44TeqFSyrbTeUP2nhs8kNAVgHmJL@AA48WSths5kUqyf45oNyO@Ruu8h7Rx3XXPso@ATEAj4u4@DLCEB1HuU5l2jirrp7RgZ1VxQGg0UMRNuvNnINFvNi2Yv1byKpzF1sqrXQD8E5jVJjOSB60zHILg1chUJeFuyka20qp1aPBPfSiRKkgUZ6cnkR6VkSue4TsQNoKlEsxkHlPrYaXSHLsGbpbVkMkQUlKNvgpZhWYm4fFGC/DvJVjIVh7TJeBrYci0eB7zQgqNHlcYZAU5Ej8wZoBI6Jgxx0TUFYpC0OIXd9RvGeDh3oxHCWTeQsnEGfbFXBbf0IBePcsk3PH1UoFvS9AO5l8cD4RYn71BeGs85dxd4SZvK0s6oYNw9k/ojZ6Irn8mgNMmR4TK@EVckCUZCCuGQqNpPTQ@7sG4bztSLzjSunADF3MH3ZDgFZhlsT0sDVZljwegOHRbfvA/QWbjeg0MJLl1JfAEsANDryvBDJopSCS6WgHRBG4pM4Iu0FYtmZVQqBGc9wdx8vjB@LYe5VSkNy2BG5sB2XEMClEAKgXZP0Z48oR6sSx/QzNeNdQk/lIY0VLxNAzjiI8vRCbecXUfWg8ajSHrQzyHJkdETLOAffWCPMm8L1@gpWwKt0jruEEYIqA1yYi1srZEfoDjeuCdPZpBUSOCAGw3k2h0Ineesp2laoZvvV4IwpApA9hAaCbVSG1TcIEhSITDpN/I@nxYKdPRPDx/u87kTGmxxeMV5tPbI6U1BrvT1piPDHqTZPtCTaTsjE9AQpH9zah05zoRr@fCybmaGK83maGrpNOdzfVrm1nRdp@NYNBV0W9JF/Knr6ZbOJ6GC0N3PnoKs//zkuCZXIpEU/Wx0a944D7k6W47Pg@iaI623BstDHidMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDYK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjguSnuhauR/Nun3l7yz5H0qIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xGiR8jwSbgxdihMFVKA44f7QtfGKFI/vbpHDlcWn4SaEoWEFS4tHILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHejfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVygYpqJq0sH@jquE2DY8m2wVKUhU8BdSJmZaRmrPifusyrniEhj4Tm83ZRxntC9BLcLfk5j1lYFRpj9MafFWDkLgvw3bmTAKJD2PxievuEPgMS82WUQntM7X7jtWT@CoZEAzj@hU2kL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2fN@Bea9L6zQiR3aIhIOg@F@zyNH12yRow5J3J3tgyJy12JU@c9tDfKWVf31fKZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdo48/a2RaHIIw0nHlq8RbcRZsTwbBGQQl3EcOLtypMzEnJAnQTgQT66vKUKgZLZJA8QEGz6DKwoz8GmHRL43LRV36BmiqCQNL7s1HaWYkr@S@pU8mhs1pji8/rkc3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8OgiFV2fPJw/@hIBsr1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNZVOsBktPIV9lEvzj7CNElU2wXoaqB9tP30QNRVIHrQPyB35B0Dw02AZxIXX7rgTetdlJBLaD6CcL9Vd0I4CoEljCTUiYBVVpb/uc1VLb@cFaD4FGES0J24VwHcmkl5apuvZQ8GGpJbIUqcK6swXtQ2E8TFNtWkv6FuhEvHoGGR0Ag1aDSY9Aa4HEQWWatV5XsAIC4qYO4AsSuK1BS0i72mBk1fA28QaQiCn7z2lr1oZKRyK7W5ChRtLvM3oPP6R@AihGXQnrEy280E9fcbHZmXga8Fcs79nNTpa6cvKmyTO0Q@50zRgw1TxHRof9XyPqnlXVjQyZCV0FQMViRgCTH/eIBPsxROnB90HkxGHokkuwiRriHK2eUl4ZBtaoxwCC6V8ca4CrRPYExPHKjNE/9oQFQ6oN7qbyTBPtsUxEDNWl6pxRAuwitn16RT6UyMpuPSoWmfOrTeE7raGVnNo0QYph6dWjdT4iZUui1FDcvA42rrSueNOn26rYhAyx7@gjp50IS6LwuDEKkrR/SgufUVOS9vIlnK1t@eSiMtuJn0@o6YUrlEkfudjrkuKiAB94UFzxXRgEkhPWtyTlaDswY4FQPjETAurr0sqn59/xFbwru/j9Z//udv9gD/N1tnCAMFzjyGjjYM3dhSUn9tY/lJ8YVuqxuWT5BPLVMnxJDrLpBd3YUq6VboWA2aFuElCYb/ES4p@C0OtIk3kBpvITNecr4iGDxXZ7JqUc0GltldF/fafiyeFS3/gGLXIyRwIcg0KBGxLt4IxowvwURUbGRjdxcq2DTFiJh5uw@nkym/g@B6ZyOaY/zd1jf9mJm83lENhe9cv6XJXf102nOk8ekglFMLK@Iuak9rwBKIA/5ycBudq6vPK8h3ggfPddEWQ5tyTo@7qMKzp95Y6pAW3uNv1BFGt@TgWvy@LorpH94LHeuxZlp0e09K9KEDofi7IRTcaypFkGZeQ7Old@Yogww/nMrCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0qrC/w/WOVoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatRI4DUndq6e7CdQuJL8oRLCOsm5H2h41nZtcBcWDM1KKsasHQERkwiGUGW@MWGeF2YrpFtj@Yq9AYHCeRQtdqFuB0J7hldA1NvQdD41s1cUNshEhkZx2mus45/taKD0NQTfl99Yj2ZmWp3oM5SVbX0mEcXzscLE0O4uTjHYR6bnoG3VYj9nRlQSdda6X/chcIpv2i03h3kbVnWo7Hjul@G4IGLmCB31cTdBSXpm5LNBkedd/Cg4I9DosG1a2BYxVKA0WH29pWn7p95Pv@8305XMihVPUODhWIP46t@s@1fP1UcU/vaiA6sOji/taI85YhdhWb8tde1tcOFANcuFtds0eZEqWUFT7VtyZjXHI51@fB82cYOtahNhg6xnMSp0G6wwTlEjgmLhexf5bccrfn1ns/pnQDbPGuSkQa99QyYLCi@40mZVpG/cAUaibz/iyqb02NqbFS0TjsvDLwWP0tSsb7FyrjV2PTn6nHxQE8mhLGeuNrhu9Vahyn8e1WZqJbZte4W5RZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdNxMMbCn46VWXdLO7KPbUTYcB13a6S2VDkM@lA@V7pCUluRzz6DfrRoT1/Bwg1gtn8lkfAEmsuKy9HKbJpUN074y@X0pY/JZ5LyIi6tsbsS5Og9CS3QL4loWpK1T7ClyuazYpm1M5nh/T27acRzrQ1oKmCoeGHZAW5Voq@1tLXZD3PEPkbDF1IWHEx6d/rpJCz7a@Lol4AeV5tsaPbok9F6tKeGi5wgXpJZfb5@@iSww3ZULHm7FOSG@@dZaL0v6syGqXJKLt/Y6LqE6HcPS@WNWyN0Gryxnb4W3zDT8xVpc3OVLuoul@Ng1pjSeA7LMHmgpQ2Nk0OstUr7eQxMZ/mNtpJmDv3XBM8PoKrN9o7suwtgEvmDjfWkNOSIsTRwb9KsJ7vNDPcXCnaS@7zoOHKz6rUTywUgfGNxmy22ccjFhgbtpuFq3cK6euqjwHTRdSLYwxrGeJKBTnRpzL3iuBPh03oV2nY7unm671vm7OAf6Hr193RbWm0OsPXSG9tAY8n3j4du6zgH0OOE2dm4rOpR6MMStbOPx0hb3KD4tx7LeB5/IGjmjdJz@yjLt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PmAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjXPKNgZOpzs07yq0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a6IGZNJD9FbtkxArzuXkV5q0fBjfBysa3R/9ogPa6HjFnll1QwdHcuWxvpp1@OzoehiFZwQjvRGfni7QsffK6@n5mQBNLKXKZze5csS6FhXdn/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tiLZWSkI4CuWRkQOBR12W7vM8t0sWyWX5bV6BoLalEkX0pH4Juf@8PzQ6akXlb8F@ir6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491aNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBTTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohx818tTLtN0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr5wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a66gCiLZVduL7oT99anumV@fQs3WERtabODLkG70aD@@rYD3VB@Y3cdLDREW0kewv9OTP5bIH71utsX50PRwR1PouGViCkmOEzFSXRv0hhUxr8/bh8YqFh2IH4NcGXvV3LoznuNpsTm5bptWNyc0y@o/16mO6zaB3VqI8@loPPX8x@oy0J6p6Cz06JT8vXMTgEuvgbWyoW5NVs9UR6ZcQQrzB8WFc500/g3TcgbsG6UMA6ENhDAUzlcQzgMYnp/hhhzXXkGJlPd7LnviRIfk8oq9hrY1skwybXNy@2zOZIKbc4InVoaPHHhCQXmCd/n@h0KQTlZj5Mndsv7iaPId4ztQ3rEzdbsGOkN7I1G1wM/V2At2H@OJDgftpZxHtbSuY0H3Aoe1sst0HXs6kdypfeuoULh1VKigtakIGbDE1/efPk9GqYF2a98lhQb2yBautRsGrhGZaYMgtp6PLscOdImH3E7SEW0VviPNLhpz6hK7fuis0neezWEAeW@FCZj/dPTQ6OKy4Z15f@o8dWwHRqMxMMrRkcHP/C9t9FidEJM9wVPtgJ/endkcE9g1gxCXNvSx0YH2tRau9xmLOOCH@kRfMxTR3CDpf6HrTloxrY7hvqJJv4h7nUq7XKDHxox0i/UEw/ugNOl2uUiM83FLfWRpxcYbO47N78RtM/BQn97OVWAooNv7L5TLuBF/aV5gpX62XNXDM75LxOhxoxTr6uoaHcfi91v2JNkm3xOgu6bhKU/QxgH5FXJMAunLu5WHFG/lIQvVCCTZM92jRfrVqsYCpDr7gC1AQ93tOrgS5jtu2Z0TMUxwB5sO9/bzjQMdQPwMOJbenfrGQu8qljXqjOi2VmGItOaR0cFTQR2y5jHRZzcbk88M@aYMIju6QgMAAbvCTl1giWegjSTvHraW9KhlrJpjuhGnXrtcTpt1JNs0um90nDVzCF@LuemlcKiz8ik518xVR7oRzSIrOp10X9mTlreugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xum94OzKysWA@ZjgxcZF5ehVkrujrekCrrrF5PD5mra0i@rT/gJaHdPy4fSrtrJU8ED/@HDz5RYBBuF3KB6RFgXXev4EPhp67tP96HAp853qRvzg6h3HgKYB07wWrlIQk8eM9A19a6SkDr2VOLzz4MIvuuRj1SxySywixJFrHriSEZ9plEhuBmN2vk8ENfyi5a750YPcm3g4ArDdKT4PxXGM1/rlhAjfJG3OypKhyxs0LO3/65CrnnAWcAecuZSGOPnsrYe3bw5PBEHnvqyvFpd4inI27IcUuGFbRSJjIl9Up3I@udfDtaz/QmyoNjVdp7ciBjhDX45isaEjxwZW7psXbeM7DiquhrtSAMNSarBcTHJ0@fpBZHNFlib@g6IyMZDd47Pk7jSZNPjlcGR1M/gt7Rd2Zrkx/sq2pyBfk@t2l1cB33XJHTOkgnBmijQIyPuV2WO4WrrjM2eifzsfEZDJ7Iwb33zL6wtpKf6mfmAHshK69FFHVUVpYLuWRkZzYo24YbPte156k5Rm7ZpYfCH2u3o6DkkFXc7Grp4bYV/@tSDMv4OxE@LJGauUmtUTvCiu79fQumquo6PB/rfWhXll/bWMsRVq0PW87ZeywlG77yIoVe0gSoSjLv3EdelEbAuhW84fS87wnOztptMLcBCL0LKzv8uWHPdVuitazbxIsKpMZNbbdG@YbxHgtS4Q6fMzRWvnKNL9xSzxJdcibvyPjEjSTZ23twcFeCIx@Xt8f6@NPn7JnuoRGS2yNGS2y8R4kXktErCeet0ALe2uXUngugtFvhDcar@3OFHetuz7Hns7sX4egMKg7tZFw4hIVvFMmwzJm5aqzq8nmtZ6u3Gd2VNz/E4cyX5OCocRof0Ltv/zNVzWTI9BA@1Qx/vaNlgg7OEujS52jPLhp0chCyhi7KLTJ4JFdqo0@MGW5H4bPBq5T6leNb4Zaxr5hcP5zcFla6JSx3S343wtCTZeWMegvA/C1hLC@HwU8c63zoyHu6a3gr9h@vLNBtFSnfUpFyhDv71tJpYdF3rxfx8eiC/1hJrSfGxM2Nh07HzK2sw24fjUyyp2gs/Wa4v51Cd2l7y8Dxj3zw99X5nU@NlRk91d@sDiBOc7oyCJigMZzSkYibwcsLpB2QeQ17YHL7iuyBM9mnt1sUs/DE8@q9COb44XS8vsTAG/GTFNfZ@VLEz0Fnds499gCPxi3E9BW6P@6PW@2/TqZl4cQgmhl9fLIbUNfhsaJFclyU4otnS954eHRyeBzxc43ZbJ3SK83W6ZArQxa5fnqSW8p2u/7ibAWy1p83AnED@HH4XCsHcWb3yfFNloDq23AysoKQT3R7MWO61GA9Z0InDVcGPpvPaBvlypYe8l1sq8Lc7grvJcUeBmTThLw9pd1Gy/rt9jqqPDG@oLUHEIPYhIslHKhveMmY5YZBCSnJ2o7qnC6En6XiHo@Hpj1bGTRal4Z2kSZeeau7wS47tpxz9iS0KrSOPWirgetnhr2OOa06rCiVs7dLYdlrItW6duFfL/Ef65rkwTpB7RrPwA0Rt3ETTH/UVR4FL59pyTvjf3IcRL877p7l4Px9z5yOVkTmB3GhHaNG3L20b4aHH1znx4U9ObC0n0jYqVQyufxZo@jZZzR1nNhEU5@bdM4Z4l5esg3/bDEEiMFpZf80NVoENO2pgceh@cdOJrVNyKZWU/NltoPfEaqAJpOkHNGL7K4FeTXY5oV/ULhSUa/YRo2JFZH5R7VDM8rcFDDARSOmUCcmnapscwIhm8ExY0ZftWCXjGZHQB1T8xl4k5WowYWqfxAbirR58ezg2f7xye7J8@NGpnXlH9QOKmHbkFtgDuKjbE@EuvtoA6mLGwYnAwEWZEdf3MBZFS@oF8Ov@CxXrbZUtUWlxB1Ms3lh24pCZ9UV6QrKJ4k8NwpF3gFeHHZQY2of30xBhR8bp9Pv0EQctEh5QptVWGZVxmMdJIhN2w@//tErCsWPolXws2iYsW/LGQhx4Dg9P0fPYHdfQY6Pdg@ePD/aZ0EBF0RzbvYmw1o5z019c/sZ0E59kzbv1VjcTxKHtqrV4o/igJi4HGcVsi5AZraBziFagB20S@Cn3mKJTYIPGIyHjaL8528qV3EZ96EnIW48KFQcsgWSJ0LZ2NhgJ0Ak7OHRwWf7RwzLv/@QvBFFCIKd4NHmP/tRj3@oIjA9FHwQzh3RcE@mW4SoeYPgzP/CLAHinLrueP1n4ejDEHT4P/wiRfhJHUGgD5YA3Z6T1cBrFuWSZOSJf8bON/gXZEQkFBi3xyUPNN7neuzM9Ew0PYBl6KMtvWVix11SZD9SZrv4zTv8sp5OX02Bok/tCbdX5VutiQGlySHLSbNNKiz/xooYiRjf3gBi7xggCTLPNkGumFTYK6BEXFaocNMUklSP30gSgK6QS0LpIRLxhvE9T2m6yrtf/SfKoMrAPQH3d3z3LPMA3n7Zf@uD@1e4@4WChHbTWN@iLNECoYFNvwa8ICH@EfeRT/3Z3BzIAnFoUzDgq8wcQTOdEdYxOs@B3yVgxws4icZn0GhAbtBivhkQnp/hthJo4bOiKEhSqJ3IdAjDmPEdkdcsfRbyhZyqQCGlswAgmeYf4FFvDjCZrEA3Ec7Mce0lSLzb29tMxCkKo1ao8pZVNu0XWfFlWNBNiCucD7FwDQZpIMkiBYTV/WQw@KTUJCZF7hVX48i4eg6MShSOoxe@2z4iRJYAZHEcGWjrfYZfhZzAwO1brO3gdxQjn23Z9AFJKoxJ5EqKgm9A41NnAuQDnXTxYSZuQAN3BPMREE1BevxbqWQoFulRvtmzFue@g@/D@H1NRh7AQWUz1wfTaNuKnyOIYwRREVeRb@MFa06adkvhtMmATH@4gphtcP@SMlhDs7zeuzfNhCauG/lEZLH7x7aDczGPoDIsoSlaVlELyUWVcrmVVfJr5GcD1UFbRJeQHbApYBldw3zljL3dvf2DTw6fHd8whUkx49ejAd@vb6eakpxutEJHPFqt5SZ58Eg5fvrgUdAQi0IXItwYGL9fE/W2miymWBHk4sjO9aqtKuH12q0v8ef8UP/18ma124pGiW6UQ818QL60bV56RIffrmeulVZhK5@/rUgLeEoE9B4/uXyjqInkxVWjtV1v2rH4TUpY0RFexOQt7ATganpbmwoS@83KYcXCrxif4PfhvGhfzK7ui@JmFi2toeGEiXO6sEXne0QCIvUNsgEWKchKEHVt7zvkMvrCYqLGv7LMTbRFDVBFClzI3IbxCKiT4IPNyEUW9l59U6dD0OEtsyMEhr@4ydPAMmNo7ZQb7UokBf@rITzjhP8J51llJtMeuUQSuR3BSrPbrKcG8JICdGiU7p5NQU195oy5FXnaC/HQCFxHDrDfh1M@d2KwT6YjiNenx5FB61LAuSVIDJiMh0XlshRwCd946iyF5mkhvwaaUPUrLo96@cQsKQ@NWc8cAG9PJNPA0T5S1RYLDaxipcmgqh0Xqc0WrXBrV/wYz6NH0f5BVnZniwLoDV027Z4xS8TP48lKC/JH//j552fxpLiKlsjar2/@tnfd7G9Y/KJ6OyfRJ37vDGzqruIW5fJNLgF@1wFz83PBJ6zKZXnoCfRJwhpK7scT9wk4QYxI9Ef6mCWmNjfdJzN6TTQTdppsmkl1bhbUZqkUKVTwoACZUco@ufj4ndDtOUsoNfxqJfh6dg8fb8wxa6iy3AI3ZZJkm/hpuT2QuNCYZVIAHRiSVAhsDUkI1AwoEe8kMidwSIPhEBceZABxRTB9aYum7x3ECdWa1e@xyKcClyVHsVyu@A26zBXLDKjvJjuUFQB7g88Fcj1g17fqAzgD9VcWYgtGfpPjxSjfGC/IY98cEBQnFjHlG1gJYgBrYWi3O3Txl9i3oa@AfFCpPD951C4lFZGFZoUGrtnD5SVujT5U8fzvB0E3VZaixqtco/sYk6EBxza3W4R2BB9RhxGvsdRYFA3XP0y/oE1VvZXq/YR@K0DMHA4A/vHLdgAOjW4G804rwlYz@5/@NIbCRmJTVU/b7lkqns9U4aZW8yzPPtpsStJmI1O7v6mDFjV5PWuCTq5s5R6eGcN@72CgNEWRZVlOUbYuLi7ij7aemS/yrCD1TK3weja/yhayr2dXWbX0@nSsFhry61lLLNXSpy327NkXb9tvk@LsbP5abCa02N7hpajmUOWPVcrsYqeQjZ2WQf2EfBk7ZW/gOu0z/Cf3m17EraO70wcVNi6yWLOJ360Xi6KiNOIt@Cd1/yVcXPFv1OW6vNN6@zbZ0PXJbM5M0xx7vR78nCFIkFrymIG@fA84PU@gsCY9SYPCazTr35xPyDM22zUGg@m@XtfwZK58v12dm9NHk6ff@Dy4nuP15iiS7I3/LdtUKiFJjRXzFJW2no/hV3H/7McbV@mLZ@3tP/vWSDE28HGIj@9cPUX3sZr/aGPjowcPcrm0pmnc/ewbz35@d3c39zCdf9bI7@SkzMb2n/7JxoambWvKRsvz1Fa8cXr6hahlcqL8Z78Tbz979nXPq2f/z2@@rat4K8LtjBWBT8CVZSo48V6Cn4oy1vtesTcxoHI1Nqe/dizwv9hgan2n@F@@d/g6NonVNeVzF56T2OtYoRTjTnDAWzZ4O4vVY9sYrXAVmyu1Wg2cxf/ybyF9/ROAgyHzbbjV8wGswjxWl2qU5DJWL4BD1TTI9//@5jcjJeRsokZiXHDdZw24xFxRE3dacG3RtS2guUYpoyhBPHsynBgOU0v31Hv4YsILPGwD7d4bk2YMvwvODu8zdtRIpVItuS3BJb@gSSJFVbWmqt4DdiB9tFWrSVuMG6TMZvP30Kh2kqa0Bg6MmMa9z/8hrtgqz@rPDO5IiBU27r98WK9DnbL17FY9RZffkahPFUui49wXWZq9jIMK0mi9fMK4Fd26mClpYjqdvt@m9xniSpqFlIQXv8dioQ92WXbdbykJRPF9Yx8eL7aP15//b3/@/T//Hv19n37/Ae1Z2j2zr2xBpDPoEnW47lcq3XpdrLviRRPf60BHmUqpUlLaV83EFnCg1hFTMx9fxvPZ@DH/ZrfKWDNJqeGibOt@9vhejy2869ynHvXzA3hk8mB@LcixhDVyh1i7EQ@GVn/nr9Q4q7ckFIhqUkMt5FsST1UPrjJr3IdmErViWWzVtbx2yO63Z/xiw02POTHQDAsBHv3y1hd1q4chi7d61CtWD5LVF3E@NF5YXiHWaCgtgwaEwI/d36hslCqFiqa06@svIM3oK0U1DOOZFzuLhRfHbGyB0FhImtf9gqYIX1hAwexD4oFk9D7Ml1opW1DFqu/S2kysApFoWUkbtMWMKoa9Def34dqAP/qHK3zF@wb5@N4U5ea1wSrqlpZV8h8V9jUcX@@4omUVYJxg3U6n86bbAalD1zt6V1cn@lSf6XN90pl2Zp1Jd9pl2GWWZ/SzTt4pOTPGCVCWYtm8uhm7R0T9trHBjjgXarFUcDVTd17PZbntO8nh4E@SnFlMiP0DXHVVU9kWjE8ZuIFQRk7QmfFPVQUWA0HrovV2q/F2CzpoPbVNzLFVl/xSwkNu32@lpKurBrirVf9/ux46q3RxF1SudZVKbb@og/Txot5IAcgXPkhZYgRUbtdb2xQSZubn5gdvt0B@kVLbje2as0c/mTqIFM858YJzvwWAt5cKe/9@SgbXfQBQ34T@mEylNiVpA8fGhj9WQORWPRXUCsuQAGnh4uJn/IGiB734avuqftXYvrra3ob/bbpf@U/wvdq@8U@PxbUmziK8hayl2VDqTaXpM4sWvMtKHX1kpQmOOjwhXiOrlVoNdMAlt/7b/JfTi3vog0VuyVBqIbbFtmJoXTEb2xJiL999@b/gr/nuy99HeZHBn1ERYhfYrZUt1DbLXOmEG7Of2uwpv2xw4y94RR/0eFpHT5vfbFyQUpSXMqvwOf@EWiokZRyA206/jQYbZPYSot7gfUzUSgWxnVLnGotti4Uisbufu3HF4/F/9FIrF@N8ogYtDrz0PO9ppJSLckLkqpZRJfWyzo3q8@@f/Nyq6x/93LpLiF2WmVEB/HQ9xjEjxICQYooiSTBi1bdHuCcd10okVEvPal9Iz3clnEfRJ7QS1uVzBLWD/Vq5XOfLPJvPqNtsPdyCuwr/@xtQD9bsQ9xmv9YdgQTc7GfzWhNNsMekzmv8e/IG/9hJF/@OXuMfO3mDf0cT/GNPO/h38hr/djv4dzLCvwev8e/pG/x7PsC/5leyWbUqbl4QalJqWb3anImEompsp978ysSdVyzDbpi9lv91oWyuzJKx5leMGX5jvsI9@/GffPdb34rXanEpTt9syamOy9RkFbAPNfLi1ftxIVZjm@qmmrEy3YzaUTvgMFnGZZlhZqj2QFFpqyxjsMw8M2eZkaP2wGXAXwZcZqbPMgOWsTM2RIRQcE3amQm6@vAYwF8fALnwZ@IWy46a6TLIyEKhjT73iODBddluCg0WZ@JLA3RNWZUzcsFs4UdyGuLLl01lq6WVS0xGopLbjZfNeEtsimg4XSvnWGdubDRfijA0Z0ROfOjDYp4HCmw1pjSbCkcTYICweHXVbu9/@rDdVnAYaj51Dhf/h4ej6Out/6ND5@mhM3Lg//DwELqOUU/dTwGDvn@/Bgzbf@zE6tWdZoXYfsD6Y8r2TrOeldBdSAE319Av9YHXAiI86xtNIX6eQN3jHNWP6ufn1bMquc@DV3C0q4sIQTTu8J9wncMQF6gj53CdnaOD3tB5/nkzdHGH8vk5eH3OQO8K/0HBi77@V/g3/9v6f/qcJVmi0UomLq62E3Ql8S@ZvLi6uPLv9WQi4b8ktuEPPeAdk1xc1dFJkS7A1UgkW8mrK@4H90RymwOsQzbbdUq7iAfDQizMkrLlt8R/3Sdk7V/NeBXkXq5b5zPUj2JilemLfTXN5iyTSVY7wTchcJVYv6TNC8kqfRBws9NQW3/6O/Tdj50kRcrnqlV1i/EXLadVq7ngrViqVkvBy2YiUb551TM7agH0j1wumaxW4WUnAJuBV0jbYG9TrMaacG/du8czKWmXlwHMbK6QyqgZTB3klIdsDU/v@gz34uCQPpkBrCYfw2/VcFaSyNAHd/CjbnGxIt67l/A/Fr@zm7x3TytnLi9Dn/EYvNQlr3a7Z7rtNvpnLy/Ftkj7YMp5eM@ULi/VTDmlxpOOm/gUvwYIWSUklX2k1SnXMrBxLVeEYL8A@e3tQq5eL@TAp1CKJ3FNvYHFb0F542K8KsYuqA5qqcg5oFhF7@j@IOjLOCiwi6sYNSjL5ZMJYKRJkAGvYvjnIs/lw00@nwTMXIk8plou86hJliskSqmy/1fbAK0chBz@h5JaNpXbKm7dB5kX/7zZqgt5cvXCqKlXtQujgrPqV9Wu/11lNDth3LuXLQOKSplqU2i3H@6e7LbbNVEUUVCCG3oSdxfQGocbb1DN8@UWx0ilep@aWS3lGbQnjyPFYYRgJUC6om3l1RIiSTD7aFUGUCJwbWmDbQgaPfEmlDnmNsAT1BnIvAcX67EOG@DFBqi8MZNZdDGL8XC6d7thJIdffmj4SmlJvwt8jPAS/F6Y5SQKg/izJ7t7@ydpbVtiMe3R7l5aO37@IKbia37xTsFZfD/a3314@BwSPHuyv3u8//HBZ/vPn4G/x84XV8D0/fviGXWteD9nnwuv3De6YejG1DDa59Pp@Wv2yjTbJjSmNYVKOQOXeUYb6jLWF/Wqwq9revqrV7o7pou9@@G33/3wv3v3299999vffvfb3//Jl9//Nvx@BL/v8ud3/005j/effPnPfvfdb/02eP4H@P0R/H78ky9//Zv8R@9/DL//FPH7Y/8Xicd/AsD65Z98@b3f@cmXv/ID@P1L//eDm79f/fHq3/d/Yf0P033vd2@P891/C7/f47CCuN/9Le6Hzxvxf4vH@5UfvPsX/47//6n/h87ffvcv/hhv/ss//cGf/qd33/r3mlb603/97he@9@4XvvXuF77z7hf@sfbu1/@1monefvfd9//gr/7w9/7qD/9H@v8R3X/vff7f/eCf/sX/@hf/@1/8of/7Mfz@Hbh@/Bf/HrrK3/7BD/H/e3/wt3/0Q/z/n//V3/7Br/3tL/9P5PgN7vh//uW/4fe//tX/@De/@Z2/@vE3/@bXfvw3v/EHf/V//Mr/9ev/8a//@9//63/yLfT8jR//1R/98l9@69t/@Qv//C@/9eWa@7dvvX/5Hv5f/gP4vH853wfO@9TrQ32@/JnK8/fBxiIXoBOg7l969@u/CAT@Lxh79@0f4YEt@K35/5GmUpwf8bf/Dzi0m3XGkAy44Pdr7779XUTR/wAogv8QX98JX5ZC@Mt3Fi@A1t9ckeiXfvLlP/8deosZlTqt2uDYXdJKqS3Qb7bKZX/89hd0IMkvLkMLAfg5fQc51FLYd5C3vfvhN9/9zj9@98PfePfDX8bBW8qV07tpSb1jNQwi5t8jHkYsvE88jPgF5p@iKTYp9QW8sS/8wC@@@EJoXyp4MvD@Jfh@QV78YjwITw76QUEY@uNRQnbJom7fmfGdm75vmDNjjZcvW7jeCn6Ye4pkj61ANMpn2SzlF2zG@LIO@kOk2RY5Z3gnXwyeCXhb/C@cM4GlZv50LzxTCyc5/HR@Ftwp5CGb1CxcTCJZjXHpaIv70Dox5ZsrM6zBbJaagRIMDsghBUEPQByv1VKYsMbLA6@8aPUSo6KkUjWoN6bmadLtEoKYPSAokLKWOmLtrdqMJ0whvHqAjpSAXkeiqompUu0hZFibPWQIC4ET2Jcva/VSbVZHcG85PlKz1AMqEwKrpWb1t/BeI5iQTog9fAtFKdVSqXoJM8RK8uZJt3kj5alyVPcUS/ltAE/c7r9zn7GPRLUk8kWCDUQYj4331CI2RoToEN5MbfnVof/ASb8tQvgGZeXnwnj4DsmmO1xcxQgAV5JkWWbww/X3HXYfgmccVIqyhUeKQ0gRRRAFhB4M54dSQoraN0UvkH@stvXBFwLDymxubgqxupgVD2VCnaIw97RCZx9wOyCqFxUmFsoieht0ECQoC6SvUv6bcVxYizMOmH2U4r/797fYR1BNei78BCalsk7OiXEo26mUqAH8upMSXoBaIgCdEqBLQZ7VaCEvJaTTjMm1GIaxw8NDvxDk8aImpIDMtayK77icNJ1OY5BCltNyOu0/ZXqSh@w7ZAr1n/ImIpc@l800LVcF7anK0ItFVR0VVGD0fPv2LbQK7a@qHIDyyfytVlquRIHgwQ2kWNY8ODCk5coC18yZWsgxlqApVriSLCmwBNtKCnxXPi9EcCXiWqkUp3iAfTmxFey8K6hEDji9GqtjQYOLq4SlfDII3Dtke4dPn@5/ejJutZhg0Oe/jfbYdbqG5yUwbPfTh/xEhlYuJGONBoI@qWjIYIT9SoaY8cHDo4PjCuOV9psgQQWr0rqqX82yKsTG48@3Y/7OIxG/YOeIx3ivLOqW0MpZSBqrC7GugZoFLpijAlxlVeGpN3jgzECnT4tiWi2gZpekSWUm/LwzZWhflRtjgT6F5zTk7W3CgFC/kGjpAp3QWgWhXvf37DFVqB/vn0CCk0OmahlZqH/BZjJmKF0JdatmGfZgMtzEzW9iMyNG6rTZyKTxT8tm4a7mCmk1X2xtbFgXEubZpGa7wF2MV/B6IWE1vgoXE74qsK@CF1yQB25NZP6@0IPDqr85Dy2ZJfgOPVHNQzdLCjiPzcEJ4@hVBepeXggSYhvf@MaE1eugX0sHj4QYcIshC/anSWZPHsrUzL2pa1DogLGe@ZmJnyaUe6Y3tvQ5dB3ARuzq6qoPkA4eMa2u0StP0cP7VZd8OuC@mulCzK5Uam/VXFHQTiuVt1lNE8BD2FJwA9wGEADtI9hS@F/Vg0yy2ZICnEoVRXhks1kB544FoWIIjPaKvM3UahKnwWxOpa0iAn7tQp/VtPDy484@WsTNZnhcDIEANpi4LBOEFXmY/1YQ6A2Qhrvj6NvKVb9zZu7dy@IkRjaXCWcrqMbsCtpmM5vLIsaF///CA1h8NWd7XM9m1G1lDE4dnLltRQdnB5z5baUDThOc5W3FBOe0nlUz28q0LjBhm9syZWgqpSZOjBmaTuZ@Yt0zrL6MZ4tqImWgidu@bfB6kLDeq/WcLn0YvdqTTfxAPR5s5glyObHq2Ghlr4b2NugoOEskL4RB7ZyOXwtGbSCj4RbX1i2hJ3ec3lz2JnMLT@lYjluLgzgYDwIW0A2QQ3DuayebzVUarCWPnfGOoOWLqYaagQEEf2opraU3jJ1isdKTu5ahuzv5Sr6U7uEBIH@JayefqQzkL54@eTyZjI8MOhW0kytDAjR1hkaJdkqVfL7VaIhiqkHZtPCzzpw9SRsb0KcNvSfBExfAPEkrtSBxz3RrtXh8J6tqklrJZkpXwgJxiHOsYV3ApCmsWRrxfuFzgIrt2MBsKmk9bV4QFir9fv9q6yK1eBH0C4m/AX6uJD3duQhfq1IkXoVN05K5CAQfvQ/ovvDX9iqili@J1UZ18V4siNXWlXB/ZPRMHQ8DNTMXN1MVgClzqDHIqMmEq4rrOJNKx@g7rrGImFULQUReoJsRcuJVmF0zgzle3MyuEIk0u7gJJZcXr8JUQbGEqyvAO0c2oN03VFunTbMNtZxr7QMLAvLZDmzYYrTYixdCbOvos2y9Dk19kStquXwur2ULhXxRg/GmnCvkS9DZMoVMXtMASq5cKhevgK4V5W2MPlHH9i4Ceq@Qkf6EXuFWJhstlnz7qWldlLISL0ciWb26ir0VYh8dfabBALn2SsCg@5km1WvZfBlcWXRpWSgwEzRN0rJSVpXULP7f4dDw//3ja/Cv4R1SZTXhBE3PfArDJgz1NnuCJiwmDjtx8CNGA/bA6K6JsTfUaUfznut43t8jzgPdPuVBD01u7zUMeqzjl9y8kTkZronxfDxCqzWG@w8GYX/UgQIiO@QRHsDNtRxnVYQie/5sTS2fhhbWARncxDpEPzr4@PFJ5Hmyv7v3WCiwB4efPrz2yPuR8uzJ/qOT8LXIQ4Ok@RDEz@8/eXL91X/kDp8f9aeOiz/h0eHz3OIWeuGBWSEH13Kk0JuA@Dd8JcESJApQxPLFwKEKeMziHijH93xnvrBwZtD5OT8NbHrhtn9@MLwinARHhHWGnLZjsC43ToTaOhkO9GV5tVgWhDGznXNWzLCeY1k6fpa@vwGeQx2POxoo0FoWUiJmfe64Vu/c7BkbwlM8WVlW8RPgWAjhMQAZTbtkdAKEGTRD28MPxuOyVMeaGmw6Zms94YFe6HTNwRDG4HMniCB0dJ3B70MvSG9Er8ntHhOeB/ndCLFuRhdApyuJ4p4oPtYner3qGlUvU6ncu6c@c8WyOIYhWfcGxv4MqJY9h16ku/O0OJHFR6w9wHUNyxmjBuKNGyCyl7VGayen1UuZfPavf/NHf/cnvzaoqc3MXmZ75@kTlq8AZwMhlpGc6suyMmk1WrmUL5WzWildKpdyebWQz6dVLQ0KYbEMOkFGLamFUr6spku5MgghuTKE5stFXxJWAtFX2aoAWLuLX6TeJsVIHoIGxFch2ZuEnmQxPXyfMtGANKKAOuiETo5vmTUYP5maYdkiA4g667LYo0d7mUePRPEBvuAujr2MKPbwJV/KZIoPRNGgkL0SClSiw9OU0LafOOEvmcwDQPGUA0Cz@KI4xJf9As6miaKJL3u7jx5hPn180TA9RDvlIfzFCl6KEM3GFxDQCcDrEBpE2@X55Kig@/iCWWLIIx6yB2Gi@HFQHAw54tE4gMdBTXd3RfGAv@zuYsgeVTvPC/o1fNmlSxRdeAHKF8UBOAYu9DlR7IAT6V8Uu@DqznXww69/o@V0e6KL4pyjBxEkijOKrXdPRbEd@GM2n/mlySN2K/Si8lrfp5cy/omiFhQao2XDl6wo5sKXHNTt8ePP9OGkZwz4NXf5sws1ffw4q5uz6f6jzscfdwaDjjvf3f/4CIP29h6DMDKfup1Bx0/YacPlQKq9x5p@Oppfv6DWB@12RbdWBn2t3c7p9rWg9rxtYAkh1WsomX8NMKNRew@C9h637@urVpEJYBu7/gieHbwejOD5QO/woOCiIHrOOh2xiuSvKM2EgOoCrv9idzwFVmqnR3rXdar4PquxTBollnmjkGlVKYCNQOzPVK8wvJ/Au45TP8mLeWNWy7Rqs1pR49uQ@gmxOdPyppjeGO2o5XxlQ99RtVxqVkHjFU4/zuKSusMS6r2tNyzxaXJHAxVAbO7sSGJDbe1oaqlSKL7YmopisoL3nWyx8iaRiWcYw1uyUWztFPORFMViSle0SrEIghjgZALjeQdnZNqJxLmhnyaTWFqaH4AqUF3ZnOppVvuJWXpW4@Vi82R1VlOr3GIwy9wA1kPz9NPuxHE5yAGAm@1kKrgAnxDVckmEAihKIpkMmR6o68JiB@jnXz85PTn5giS@uj918cw1kHtV/dePH@/JB4fBGxqWlx@hIOq48h5yraUQLpEGXieggsiPYQwFdS7ww0OCrmPJ@7RxDqTZICAwlST7Rl7lk8dLcI6HzjnPGW0sVMlSoN01GNrdN3tMr9XBpfdYgkrF9OQ5jd7ter3Wro3IDAFUMUj1NUZG6RdgDjxe9tDyAyW/wINzfkC7lrmqdmqz2AzgtGtMUl@OnN5LLdWt9tDc/oPaA0xcbcOzUzVqhus6rgjKtFjt79i1qe3pfeOZ4aJNk4PDTZAl8DRdos@M5CZr7mPsPVRUrqS6y@xFyT6djhK6VO8kl71wWi70QOQkvh5U@oIOeOIWjatqv8YSLyDqa3h3N1miJz9I7uSqgKcHrJ0Er8zL/ss@01ghVyVFI4GwoCsRfrDeOkvW6l@DB4d9WqlAafyGPgWomBkANnsUALHH5lW1W7NYQmIzliQk5aqDWgOTX@JtWxLFliQ1LltCXZI@F@rQX6vzmF7zph36UgvLdFQtU6jOwE8t5qpDaF79xazq1sZTkA8sePVn8/hZVr0KSAXcAZg3l4l3v/jN5LaUr3G/KoG6tEDuaMvt2qxqo@1HIIxatgYBqUYukwYVHm7FNIz5WiGtFtLZdC4tFdEXBvx0Pg2eoOKAfJGwEiJjYjozy8hqWjXUdCLz0uy9TKZPEyC1ENJYMj1x9u3piIEPNBXSJr3CE9CT0rYsUL16DtO3JSJWYBlVrBhgfcjGZnqIoI4M3aIUyaTEslsJazOBcTZPpuP9RqtS2Z@Nvw5BCen1TiFVzKTeJJPVxEay5hmvhXpVqCN7oVqPN4By/YlO5k1HDWhlcKlFrdJodLCKxUw6m8lC7cz25WBbrIutdGajoEITXTFiG4zzjejcH0o8C79xG0Vvy4CmU8taVZBpIi5b0qSykt/KZ/hkIE8pjH32hphkiaYYnNtOxONFLR5Pxqu4DLEh@vPOwNOIn8WBu8bvqTsiCGNiRSxrGGHBGulobiYoHYhjVwIKhSwHmu2FcHVxtV0XviIc44HLbe0F/hVfPN09xL@vgFcZXksvnj4/fH74SGAK7fSU27HqRlWutqvwIsn1@0Kswhhw0qZvVErZYOxD95Cmtusv@LOJhwcArkD2nBusRXu7DBPVNvYZGizYYXGog@6OGpqWbTW0Iox9wE2DqJqmVnGRJobHE@Q6NIZ3AeXbTtXxrN/X2Hyup6RA17/H2CC1KRB6YtcnAnZru4Oj3WB72u7e6umCzZmCM9RNQRRxO1vsIh6LX8FfLM5PVpXy4pvg0E5BrJ5myttC7D4dStT4oUQWC48l4pqrv1ySzRVYshysZnwlfj8Wj8dx2aDCvLex2M2C1DOnVbFYyNK5u@obMecfwVs@QVRalCYXlAaqH5wY@9pLDQgzZjuBByhmOGkGA2c@j9P0MeXl2PuGVso@PTi0H7qPIqeXXtRj@LlsCQ9iVSsv2hunKhBkVsyepmPsfow274tlKJXGPaoxdsrU6gt4tuNqBYoqxJoblxsOLsCwcFvgW/uTrzM2jmdzccaatdislvP3m6v1uqRua2gPrsgqMM701YKUuazznlSngIIGIe9@8Qe52XYJ3rWMCu@alk9p9bq6pbFkbPzuy99H0z4X@5/tPmFxnLb/uz/5Ha34d3/yr2hnW/yKpvK1bDEGMdGpFoqxi4vxxcUVXDwsH2vFeKFyxSS4@bKSGqsrqpa1bbvKKoqubxVTOe2@XVX8uGpRTcY8KeZv5swW8lIioSpQqq1sKZOEsEs/ppYpwVuwoMWjiwVoEajA/pGZ19T72ztQv51sTqtuAG2p4YFXFv5tG14ZFcunLy8Zg5duvTcYmBq5FIVV3kps@620zd7ictJbaYO9rNVxW4KKx2SD5ZYtPDaIS47xekrZijPQy1i9cVW9aqVovQbU1xeGsWU3r5FncwPPjSx7bdnwZ2x59IeJAg8PXoM3Y@uVJya2korS64k3yX7bYPk6EMyWsjjMy7aCVRj@J0nN5Ltf/HVNK/zdn/zqZfuy/YUGum25XFC12E9/uj21p57Rq/8UANxi1iXQT0lERfsr6Aj1WsbNUJp@qtAhd0Glntoow/P4gZaLei0D@ccc2EaPtFzhDGU2atw2tyzYS1C0LbT6kCYdgCx5JauCEAjLXMZ3B900wWBbaDu10UoKF8JXMQhEAgZ6QlX46gIUeIxACHC6bc@aumM6d5OgdGorze5BEsjhq2i0cYOsVfjjiQSMVdm6mZQX2SOskXzHRobnoQlIGAqFr0IS38C0NWdjHQ2rYEzThgFMxihUTgroNSDvFuRt8QRt8k1Q7XmENOOl44ls0AOEr4JIQ1gwQdJh5jZEqAKj@iogAOqQ8AGbLbbNskl2YaZS1YV9ySs8IYAWMPXAqIOAyRBaD42IBImrGA@8QP/AT5oiXfgtDIJmxDMAwmHwDQU10GAwOb2h8EhWV94bFMAiC2cJqhq7d29RqlrN7CUZ1Qjhn5pjnH6jdrBXlxWABdrfR72KmGZoubMa@IZkBxhPUXGB6iRusrMaScpEfL0SBPh/b6JFirzWVBRQxQr47cV7RRdQBokR7bwNu2y7xlStmGRh4btQ9i4Vio7Whyptc/aRrH0RBF5BCX8aCz4YBEzrJDql6dPtdaseDAT@KX6tBW27cWbgW@Pg1tuQ@R1MgtRhKqiKaVHsvumCskU7HQLDkYmsmsRkC0ObVA7i41qO4Vb6fBIflApjM3jqaADRz2eDDDd1HWhQb@zYZDGRLDrhOQagCOBRvrE5XuypfY5f9/LbhhJHS@SRoTmkfCwxWYCkz6JTWtxq0HFBKQ9wk2bGQGbdUY9pZZYgQiOjeHYILkmJqMAdkNkRxx3LGEGRjg2DDr95FUUZgBw37ZBlwKcm0NXwkQkjkO0p/hfolXPz1FRO0Myu5PTxjBy3sxJD0Q@7H9/V4FvhsxznlFnmqcFnqhNLVmo8BloLCN5pwOziB4it4HYZLZvGyRM1zWPBrwiPIneW0pG0G4l58uYzq24k2tiilzTemC5@Xf5MtyP4petS8NV1b@4Fdq7IWhO8yyHLNXwLN7U42q4ITTcJvsWuGhmLknEFZJwQY2Jg6Qqdwtg1zhgq3gKOMcA0u4HNGOzFUNuv0gBAfQ96FhrAnLgVtHQEJXF7iS50PZ/B2@wjltUEjMjNkPkmwwAGNn1tGTqEQVKshzfpQcPINO2PfAV656gHYWhjwyc/TB9QN7rJOOmCvNmGDw4HHcqrxni3CF7ykRfsHUjPVPUNCCxACVeUZCMhpgBsSkyKHHSY/npyTu0C8ZIKuwkpzRCCj2qAQqKCjiwHLRxGPsMlQMAD3ePfavDNY56fn8tks3XqmrLh4aepPMfWLWU8MEHGdpSJMRr7HwE28ePvPtyFS@JfpJPHw/HODKXbWvnenD8Foe/V/E1HiXjfi@PgeIZfXhqMyL4bGlbziKAemfTVtm7C3wPF6U9rpS8C@qsg/Uml@BUCYQzBzNLzdDcNwNKd7mm6f96r@gFn1CEBOLSiEXiiJWU3eBl5gcsc98MYzgT5aBjUsU5pHRkgiXyWeZE1r2EQcx68@u9jcwaJbOOc7bquPk9QeBJjIwEn5iT2sDkM@xQCThhm2AU362vOGvPWUvJZmBwGtXAXhYvG24SL24FyG88YPuPhMwif8fDZItMg28asxUUy9LrC6iDVo83PICaCmQdxrrg95EUIQQZ5HHQn8sOY8yW/K/h1a5Q6wDd/g3asBYQBNDEGhBsJpfGi2Wi2bM8432qllAEQu0iIgBYH0I0W4fS8F7oR@9aZNXa8JS8bTb3CqOSXG726Q58aOK1gHcMGIsLg@DLROudg5G/34AKBX2GAgHIYBKJosDtJmMlqaFOcAoFwGuICx7xgDb8wLZK@/CDfD8QljnqO2CigVgQQ@odVgmJCCAt6Dv8QYcAdPncdiBPElejbaSO0EhdvxQGT17oK5zVVaqRIqSQpKCagHcXV2vWqBOHQFI1rQZFqXvntHy3@xgcXvw/9YnXpiWD5gFEVol0Fd1iCCOF3F8Iqq9ci7QolULZ0y3Bh5Nrn8qk/WkM2W0qgZvB8sAreuTnpDhORxu8mefvQOU7RFishKcxrNajivMa7Je8XAUo5wsNknp9sHhCCn54zEICRWZnM8JPNoslmtRpnHGy2Jtl5pJAzKuSMJ@GxZ2sK2fKTgfZ0EAwv2DwtkE5xC6gI8FQ@jIIYNBaZp58ZuCj/Ci1Y4sqGn@eC5xAV@DSEIjbSWbe1MvdGpNARpnUNABLiDQA9/k3jinCd4alS@BbyKI7KgEfxN58MOK8AAiMWXOVWnhMhkZEODAK/mKJxAPqumGoIokqz0/iX4T8xHXgGP/WmZ2Y5prrsmUlf@/sH8WwhZiMdNCJ9qJkcMmTUZJ7bvnnUqMwRY7tTUHBAquucOyyxQtgGf2XqJ1U6ltNRRjpursEvnXJfeTxPBvoDru@w@2Nnok@cXK7ClSaTyG5V/lxnMAe2gx9Iilh6B1mv5xieHZ9Ao3adgW16RpqhEc5Tw1c7DP/TE0JUTvadjicI/jYvrsYiaE5XKOq22/jt9XY7gbsnk5VwKzhtpkTyjMcF1H/BFUkP7MkHejhOOJ1XRneSvBsmfrbAT3Zidk8Th2M/EOdkdxnwsC7I/xA6BAmGec5CcyST6ChKdyYJ@tzG0Bk5A5D6pp4sYOpr4A8WsLFA@nhMZUkzHVXaSuTjFdRLEt20nvSTfu2Dk7KvaQk9GabXlgEsISPN3Os4Rsy6K7Jrr82OJwvyO/7w8h5Hy3t8e3lJC79eZq6a13jgh2WdTSwgQMRFMbJ3FwOrDnyrd6M4S0UJvVGu4gneu4g92rzWw5LuQtRdP7rcB/pIh28evIUF/2wd/m9vwCD5/vs2nw7dnh3Pgd@McB9ogr5p5wXLtAmIfpBE3nMzu5C0H75nXhAXPyf6CEUIEGOJcdlozRk65hjUbi@cQA4A30HzuF/sBt3TJrIaD1xRJvcszU619U30sN0zLH1u9BJ@zHQEblDjI1DYiF@9X8WR0RHTc7iul4CxKxmGwjCOSOeRKmtIRk@fJZPryYpHMUPqoZlyKuHBevxh@A3WjFN8NT5bDXpAPB7D6dgzE6c/x/PxnH8wwOIfNPP5KB9/eEuiLYq7EQJ44KOnml5km7yNfR4lwiq9x4gQxpWXq4z2vAOIaOLpZht@GIrurik0biRRLWhlYflTOatb3LytxSNUEdAkX4x6P5K8i@jem@YipMaBLVjY3ocNITcg496SbjcRhch9bm0xx77BE9CP5unsNaNKewVDDVMSp5uYpG6TfJEUUDM@gCdOOH0GTwQ4MCZtTlBB3XBOy/9GKKOQkT6OSC2@DwjpACWCRY5yvxiRWELghugXV2Ge3bV5dm/k2V3KM@wBy1lGIgndpSz9VsDmua0JLKP//3b3tWttJEuav9FVpCXcqEypJGGDsbCwBQhb52Dw8GG3F9PqQipBtYWkVokPte1@ZubH3sDO/7mEvZW5h/m1V3E23ojMqixJYNx9ds88c57TplSVGRkZGRkZmRkfo1ukMz5h70x/7hLb9L9e3x/itOLzQrhQCV21cLVQIYG8ECxU6nkSygvthcoWP0QLlQN@@LRQ@Ss9JHNr4ctCxUwLFBjST354ifdahON3a6GymXe@Zkb@pyAy7XoLlXhMqcwL@ckUIVKg36Q14oqt19fdHA0DWthYqXQVOCZysX3icxiX/yvR/yX5FafFwUeccT7iwmpRlVOLhrViSDu0bJi0CzNmckWv5vW9bbbNiougmUXa49l1GDyp4bmFtDASxPCVbzToLyEIuVmZjZGyVrJ7oqNbJw7lQU63z9TzWB9o5/n7MRU@SRrhjGe6vhmvNAgZwPvhicq34TmFjmmOMcKdrDMDLRD154U7OoWxTuOiR98eIT7rThcibAumiIwSg7VkOulwfDmHxgb9QZpJ@CtcAEK7Dh/KyaQE905UY6mgZ@Ytn/m17hkEgz35nbu6Y9UDaikRhI/HpROZZfG6wLIYnxJZZ2mqMvkIBUvm0AwPWp84m9yWfuRyIm5cXituW4ZMXWmSJVdaTFJlD7G1Lv2RtB5vXuuIuPV921dT8wZnLXkAsGrGrYh87X@H/t4X/d0o1IYIEw3MUqxnL6XT6vWdq@wE5t2k2ekBxEdXbTkzlaO4hYTktDuwNPO7eG1KxYfJhyj50mgMfULbN2SL9wTfoNvk3kJgQUsYXqVfflqil5@WbifUtEbSvfKM0uKhJQ1HOh5jmnTtblyl47OGGF/4fNvvfvcAD9MDbA8e4HEHhhMkl1k@vOyxlUsyt0lsyxuI1HJFiSDn69J4mJOXJO756ja@tqUXe839rb3dnQ@06D59@tTRa/Q4wQ@zFmet8ToukNnQO14PZmxbllykfMJlN47jo/P@cPTgYy87JUtEWJMy4FMrhv30HHe0LLPk@cTcpXpS1qKohvUpmQZ@SipB1fGxZIeariMiSDDKP/I1EKPeEr1d3q05nNyo2ez5F0GzycuXyW@sVzEMjbkRd/6We1C8jIacx1cyc11nMhzkQm3tqfeva4fq8HVdbR9t/lV92DtS72u7h4hv8PZoY6exqei/@u5BXWVSNpLIYogNJdF1K2gFSE2rlkqlJ4ohb/YHY5E7@U1H3h/4F@p1vxXgmup55F@8PJcfXi8YrUutOm1HxzjDDDlr5UU4gr0Fp1mkbSyUmza7LcIzQVHZU9rTXmDPe9Fvh52Qymaw9x2EQWQ83VQ3pBEkeWucvV1RkpBRkU2HOFMqLLCuqbpP5XF3Q2B8sb8CiVFCUjC2PaUJF//vuyl4WN9/c6AQKmNzb3ercdjY2z1Q23v79PPth8buK6Jn4@Bwv7FxhE9c8M3eVmO7sVnjF4JAyVOIYfHLZTS6EwUPxZkqrU@4@fYGNPzxr/SpNzR4de2zA2ekFi57kD6h3w1/C9oLa5nLCOoLnEb5qkDl52v7r97Rmq@CX3HDaa6C2f4gexRxls/5knrOrdFkWaf5tqanKy17hbLD9xEXY4VEP8Eax7bI87OrDHA24mmHgcpuwkYFZ98SAoPnsgFNDT0g2ABlDFaqihN0LSy4zxnkOrXW6vYRr1RaEyNC/QNVXxpTk7UMU0zbygAofC8aPZwHldfiF8T39GJJNzsaSgH1OH4hBdQTeQFVtAHbEbWsS1yO9i4hntWKvPjlYrDN18Lqafxiw@dd7KrGScaNh9RXcYJDBATpcho2OeXhVLGc/JyrRFweKcq6XZkYgSTHJJkoV4ls20YlsyRsOrhq0GZvknMaX4kbYCfkd0aRylcdTx3COCjohZIA76zr98QEKjHdYd5Tq4i9VNX@4WGcOI69WQZ9ZkAkrUzjEdfb0lphcN96VHNjqkVf20hy8lZjgvYtBDamEPgjYAhQIbXTafFKxT61ANPvaFbOR33iSJzb/m6XJ3ZuX7aCVAVttZX/JfztN0cT2U3tk4ydImNHQ/RbMCS1kq8yO/0hzXEWq5xqC1Kwdd4fjEIZw3y6B3zjxMsclcbCRq39XF1PtQY6TLbY6/esRk@Ji29p9ZSY8j6tMsfL3XksvpIczMT5tAiL3R3Q8U/7V4F1d@biEuk6wPELKcJ8V47Dz/GIMRH9M5PIjt8VUreuVte3Nj4Wfv/ZRf5WEQuSPtkYHeI/Yky0RdOD7/nYYHEIvUvPNJN3L7o8RW1tg6elJWa5AUb7wPOQ9nUvm2vxNzE3nn4PT5/J9/zyy5eq1CpAMumc29F5PpFurjo2Tbpc50RpExBLdhKyJOvz5o3LMGN5/RLePRgFBBPqQY5g3z6R1U6LENO708sOSRadXFgPdwzfUetsUZFkZofXjj0exZ/yG9XFdaeYGJQoi5x5I6JdA7nsOJZZCq9XU@C27gZH8vv@4FbvxE6Wh@@CtnUntO/CrbB4OyxZlixY9wf7@x1gZXH7Q2Cp7@7tgGWRnIYWc3rMnO58LramvbvFn6fGjucegcHaixOUGKjV2mWPr6hN9O@8VHBsMIlCdHC4Vd/fV1nZn1BdknvYMrS1GATsB@ptYm0b9ljYebHSFG@WY@XJvElZtMV@VHdM5pnEu0VUaB3E1fSIhUUSY7wT3ojU0ysLqxBsfc8C0VAujd1nI4OiYw34K@0BCdlk0KwOZmZ2MyeLTxjZRuCabq7oxrYNP1tYy9qNlL3DsQ3Itgnyz@BZMnv83ot@XDHtiIKFCEzocJs0aVpvaJ9wQA0PqKDnpUfwjmExQwoje1Gwc4Z2MPwqpTXsP89QzEiihIsubIl1rRxr1EQ/njdqDhskYhnwYempP4pFM30wIp7fPLcH1EkWvXx6CSIlE0lcX9pcQdVPvuoljKkRr5PVWCG359o8Y3NssDzB6ayGvXZ7oYewhV6ZFA@TTZG0vbOpwt@nKVklUi0Zms/sjPlIkFeWlx9/C/ZkL0z1wp@FLWvIpPwcXQxof5@AjMYRH@8T5zZ2XfM9YYA7SCem9WbCTFQkVWfGmpLqOy9GNn6Ei5wLETIImY@8uJOtOupmArfZ0GVFsqFzkak@WFM47qjMminqf727OQjkb7b34Pvbk8mGQjAd/Aqr/Df9YRQkXnlWuBnrFdz00@@C4bDHxcSf6QJQ8uzGdKezHXvbicGr9Aof@b7N7klHeyeJ2a1rzhq4ET5e9JAKG6d7a5PHe4Xymt3V7cZOXT3iEJqd1Flkdph1LNnzIOzdhQDLYD6XwPLBPnwPowr9Rzi4BiSRib358kwb55u4MUVIaz7mnEraLFTL1vLk6Heilt9DgBI3@zBSWfcHqsinsPW9bWfWyXppLVWfkIsGvTzVcrMFL8tV6R0OdAEpDUJGE@@tBQueGsZSEu41Z33YR@FiK7iR0zO2nPSL5dXSyrMM967njtyL42cn7qNWNato8fV7F9Hl8Lr96ax/ftVRXTX45fSmNf7tV6WWn6jH1NbSDxLHuLxSLXLo2Kf076p6VmLO1Qi@4JjMSM3sSc5apRZUsg9fe6AcfuBNcwUeEhNcqh5dGC6Ei92oenG8clLtVUtrF8e9kzU4@Y0Wq6PF8mIeL36gVZRkjNzMH49OsKbap65B70ohWijnRtWuIYpdQ@jNG38Y9ndqu69Sp3FQAHAEpm29@UBd0mDPwZoNvideL7jO62MyV4FjM1CQMnPsFVSGFz6fJ@M4ph0SZjQqLmmz0Q3/O3YycyXvcjDq8xcTGxKspb6EXzJzxo2pxCcKVOQ4NBEk4V9AcJIyeVwMyduxWFEXyqKuleE76VggjlGTxWH2YzYLn0Igqn25jk8ykRf4rXMggbzvX7iaev6cs8ATq0Uen@LBlMMfssNE6QSPuAChPwO@bUATrLlH7PaRoe7jdxkP8obPqEbsJ8MG8hnWFPEF5t/qM/s3cf3nRAAh/JzoXJ4@4tSaFymS4jvIhwsIvJbe@OOaAW6VMihz6CxgS3vVBDhbijON0KwmE72fuwY5hVb0P92DQpl/TXUjLu9IcSYJ31PrXxFoyUPKn9bxp5tUy1vVCqaaKWyRYu6b1MBJF22P3gQ0rcZqM@h2CWmhxVxCDjyyf69ufzFuPzpGmycx8vK9MPW9kPruyXdBKinl0QKfFKrYhbK5z0m5ryqbFHOn2qoqVl48GumWRypJUnbtrrKRN@o3w6TwejyUwpXxh@epDwXry08zRl@@PEjViRk8/n4s3zV/L@mRj7FMlX2Zbh9/M3qAAjae1bYmE1zq9cLui4xOGa6/gM2yRE2lpDqnglRmUlW1D6YWJ6TB4Zyfp@16NYGyWDYSh@dMdv35y6ynlYwX@Uk0xItxamLNmCMWlbjNRSbcDTssUjv8@YEFgmGC0ZSZueum8lhXHltgUeqBaVa8IKcmOHVtcopX4Rf5Bf@YyZ5GzpTLzf44J5jfSOfFuzlNIBa6D7KzyZSWJnAXkZe6U3esIknb40mIs4XErnUKHLcZiA92B8fgD2I5YQsKIymm6B5/0ZROCpQN@942hPj4NfO34qPMK5907EE3uFE1bDN89sLKpBzcR0E0ihCiiqPnRJeDQRe3jqzwXbMLtQ7Nv7SM65YEorWye5kGLHukvIsn7ZBOlTy1B8jXMBBJPkSXZ2dwJoMHbP8aohUnLuHIy9R6YznQoDnzeEnczAOF4BssgLvhmY2EjJzMHlA6GvitwMuQjhaR9pORrnZCnUCVz9PhN4JIaLSkVTKZf7oMW582X@E@92m59LhskexKXweXvMdPEgcrIpL5sIRghsvlJ5mMdTfckrvhAgC6agcL/TvizeAq6PWCTI1WDC4YkdIaBcOroO1lMvtBfAkMuGBl3EzCD7t/OWzJ4Q4pXT4xI7yEI1euw4jD8Bfrs1wXt/iuzM3g0iq5baahvgrbIKDxOOn0cTvMFxYIEyD0QKWLYEREeeSoNEp896xxYd3lAgdRRA3EObHuJmIy9PqjsEUjwydZmS6BkmuQpLFeewITaq/V9eEc7M1CAO4xCQUMAuYq6S4cMvrS/LtwULpj5o7dNyNTJOnX57lC0z0YhiR9EwLzqHA1C3ca4MPXjQN1sLd9@L62X1f0/HZ/711jq76lNj7wHTcuyjkqsHq9t0PSJb5Nl1vzPXqRrR1QzSx/yNR2P6j6j2/36wcHam9fNd683WkQNAK/X9s9bNQPXNXY3dw52uLbd4KgdvcO1U7jTeOQih3uudyqqZZJ6qm9bfWmvr/5mn7WNho7jcMP3OJ243AXjeFWv6be1vYPG5tHO7V99fZo/@3eQV2hY5mtxsHmTq3xpr7lUfvUpqq/q@8eqoPXtZ2diY7uvd@t7ys2ErB6uVEnLGsbtIVFS9zPrcZ@ffMQHUqeNol4hOCOqw7e1jcbeKj/WKfu1PY/uBroQf2fjqgQfVRbtTe1V9S5TP4bVKFx2TzaryOCEihxcLRxcNg4PDqsq1d7e1tM64P6/rvGZv1gTWV29g6YYEcHdVchvSM3TTCIWvSdnjeODhpMt8buIa0ZR29h7@DQIL8nwhCWNaq6xQSGGQR6S0Ta2/8AqKADD4Cr3r@u0/t90JSpVQMVYFGxeWgXowaJiId2N9Vu/dVO41V9d7OOz3sA875xUHdowBoHKNCAQcYHYh1q9Ih7jXEivOSRmDVjONfl4VSNbVXbetcA5ro0ccBBQ3MLk23ztaa5h7DB1iFK2MeZgX9hH6x0pl9dBQiUOX0iM/uMJo6YtLm3VacVWQe7yiYfjmjVWZ0IpWR/o5Um/kg/UyFr2sHp5Vkz7HX68DGNq8nBx0V05iJpkYOMLx8zd@Tu0ucrXCGXazbf1Zq00T1oNh33PjVTaHyrhj4Gv6uUo/uIjBDYeePgp1IRuj9PEWr9B33RyYZ6uIBASaH@D2L65l8EjioW24GuBud9ADZHR5Fcm5zjKoVEIzs7IlVN0iSfTPDvULMDV8wb8F6riXNSWEZyoX5E//S@JD9kcbBekHSW465iEZtYRiP8LTDNSCMcEoH/0REJwg436UVB8OksX7Kbw57fO@v323nHMXW47Ij2gWd55xvVT4OzieqFyfqMLF8762QKkdl3swoT3z9rkik9Lt6Qe5bHP80R/3EMNhLzAaem3BQfVutDy/wPUh0WSa7SoS3gXsGDDJ3vTe3Hxnvs5kpLT9Ym3r@O38vcgr0gQurSgnfM9U74z@sTKUATjGNxEElCHSGjWLTqGHuTuPA1FTxHoeuwDcsfWqvPA17XiSSkyF76XbtNrMbD8MbGnuTwq/3am42j7W0SncD2yery05W1TBx260dX/n5AOxz1lqOODWgdJz2NP1mzZJMUH54pVtDxhP2ZgYtFFEQ0eTNo/BJxHmK7jbQlEwQZuhshb1MPJnrZAHTIKg7A8SBj@HXmzNQMkE911UFvLvwbVvF90pWYB7QxS3fMo3aDfwA7nv5miscd0gykWYzjABPn0u6C5V5225iK8uaGA/egiJc1fCxh3GIa8FEX28/Cu5Z/ad62RjESU0bMVx52rklIPJjEQhm7ip7M7LccZ0QfAHP0MHrzo@Y3evygA9xxuDs/GtVGB0TG7bgmzqmTw2jd6WMN@QTZPRBUzbT0XOGU39FI8dzTx8lxYBBrNjAqSFUDG9804LU4jshkk2wB@3LBUZ@FUxG8A3DWNMfq38S5s7qjoayZ@CH6t4lKoQRWHOREqHYdt5ExRT7EcSwMOVNk@lP0YPj/QJrMgP@cdpwEPaGWFQTwXpRkqEIr2r4yUcJrc9Fg3W4k1LRffUjAfLUH5jzumL69uRH/GiKBHp2xefGBwx528jMIACbHwYY9f2OTtHOftk4vs46ujnuSXutikFd6rTBLxRTcwsqJy2qXa@5W8MNRjpw1WQ3uUFX1UjZupzzracs0sZVXD6OsgHNM/I/iIz4AiSc8c@m5WK1OclZJzzIjB3SoJWvBaccRk0gt/Xrrrd0jZYXITMl@ffNlCEWg14HPdD85zUlfiXluOuIir8TqkKPgIbY5tslYfHTIulM2xOwGgPOwzYchyIQyusYC0RXoHKovgabyD9lQBI0kVodJnEGIW8cj0vKyeh1jzyeT4NAY@6OehNUP5FTLlPAkwIfG0HaX99Qbf0wod@/XbWGx4qODvgvbRTQmxxK6PrK@tPr9IamOPvpNOLrh2PHUe33oEPSiy6GOX0jrWTjUJxJG6admoDbJ7p2XGYlnz6hF4QjeCm2P@YO7dBHAQlTCk9wUVlSemNfw6Lo5dAxvFssq/zz58pxowmFJmYjP1Yr68kVKCUF1yNCAKRhG8eaCbTa5Hdw7xNPvuj/8hLUfKlCvHbTjyKQWSD4LlEFq9DjGY2skXR/0Iz7RoKHACUhMibIcpMWGqrRGP9XspO2askl0TMQu5Z58fzsxkxprKWooYVzdOjHfSoEGE1Ra0qFB42Ch5aVlRmXWhuvrrZsxjhaavrZW2Y@9WKRURImoPjSqI55EbsZPH/CkD/mrDyPMHnqDO26tggJh6Ky4V52Wc4wfbAreh8GwbZ@JkibT9gc4fuOtT7/HvGiODnXYv5Y/ioIx7QBaxfCmyDCa@b/0z3vNzX7XPwv7oU/7NASjvxGJh8cxP2LAzob964gTGvGHtlWoPU6eJb6MhGHD7/hecs0KzRWNgkHeNlMYDce1cwkTwSfnMAJMkqkyfw8mY6TFdZ4sJ5Uyaf9TtscrO2u31n1cnlVZbvQBQAu49QkLCvEhHbFjkuV8ujZV4PSuAhaOp6qgfOcWi70Uxs@IRHwNk8LYIDNllmB3AjuzWzE@bt@4bY5BOESgpWArQHaeKM@vXR/5qUmKvIClQEWVV0tWVblFuUEcQjyMbyf30tN/MPaEwJ9Av/x4FrfMYgQWcR0TbSmS/YqOMkq4sHlgyDKaJTFJsfAs7Fnuh5wK42YSavrz@DZqsOUPKUU6zN4UV2JG5mnjg7x7@SaJnObYwaKyoBYcjtsBFaQ2ypduZ9jgW/azPPlxiSsnZxBMmxpy3kL6NlK1iErIADxhXmujLDGVvz1jlpbuO2oTBKzOMjmzMlHns0ZzYQ@UUNZXXGv1hySMsxPU06YeC9GoP1i4J/VulR0zI7PNonXLcb5pCCzMVqXF8lGbSVsd43G8lpnEZ4Jp0hRjSzPiIWxf@Tlm80ki3lSbmG/V5vgbdLiNZondVLyoxOPdlrmPRfEKFr1moYmnFOOOIKVr8fvjJnW8ebsE0TBle9VkidGEyGiO5dECNUGmmEr3pxBzn8Z9gh5tohzabRPt7PG5laiTRnIm5Kn5lApyCXoicDucNkkuDTowvkCYONFwYyEVK5w37piv8sqFUwQZxgcBCK04KCTnUHKCmwzWBB9xdoBOvglroTIkET2t2xYOcdD/mGAclV8f7miLh@a4UD5ZE0g3MSTaVXCpuyAZf3P6edy8YShTpKApPoMUcY@mZNP5/Xv1Z/tC5QiC1ObP2tK35KIzjlokbOgf@1PzBjpw0pSumZpR6YnQZNFAc4F2KWfdQLar0P7CoXA8rBv0NKINhLzO48@iroFw3iulmNqoctMeo4ijyS2zzVGFdamSMJT8Bvn1VBRVlzeuBCAQjKl@tUwQENaUscelAIfesTkvhageI6pYLWNa0kuOiprYec74DqLqAk@WrRKlWSWe2TAKM4GQYjG7TIII6SyziyRQaKGbiYtV4uns/iQlSCE2vC8Up6HQo5KmYTxyQkBOfV1yEolyXFZuSXMwf3yy7KQ@xvzNX5@VrK@lya9EnxjD40J58utqKfU11ezSUrpqqibRw7FbTX0kUjg2wrFU@HP/Y9cUO@R5bBNqbTJSWoa2z0Zqctpl0r7N@yVSz9kp2@gYBp7tGW62X01JsZIKyn53AHa1wFcGiN3@p3trLFMNJjpXAMelM84uedkQssaaxVKPbmGnayLtxQEKzJ6231HvDre3U2FfT8fG0OgiGC6XSiUw8akd/N7YVuMoKewX06WLnctutzi4/svw3WmRZX8QcEqAitlBBzQkNCkirz88k8wQwIGKonRBO7Jir3/Z6dgpGHBDicGjYZOSOhqC4gUojI1e3h3yARCD1Avsz@gg@vezimfftS@KpoZirqGoNkyCr7Lm9ozIgxcd2GfHN1UMDILZWDPRuuVU1z9jBUFmEx4sDl/sfE7Mk7Ovg26376r3SImMSAFzXycrbG/bFUpSBDeM7N17GXE8WlcFV2HX8itGEZvXAc4sTCbPhIkLj9j4@8FZ/WaQzx7/lKVlhbq8iG4uIj61q7JnWUcHi78HWOFDQvtepS/8Qb7FdJosTEu9nsHJE2H0uOzO3Pukijh8JqZp9u3SIOpsdD0O1kBdd1gXMLHseXi5J7cUj4mb/XhT7oCGJYGhcULMlfvVgKvZP04sXo06nftJRU4DIAP7XRJRMqH8OYHIdwA8A/X0I3oiivZfCzSttycCioiCg2Qd03IHFZqokMk8bFV/vc7XajU1P1hcVLXaBj0UCqq2UVNbeLGxobbo9wZ@/1BdWl5eE5m75Xymlxvm5Ve1QTD4hHOxdT7cop/0rQq/MVhrY4jni9V5d22@WX2@vhYVj2sbcOunp//8l//5n//6v4o1/ePf8WODfxz/FBfyPK843/o8/8PXNfw@3jpZmD89nh@cLJytgcv@xlHD@41RwU/MR73haSYnq4D1lu1IzT6bo8/oqspkCbzwh59IulRUrhUVc/ptJJmjWMbmWoH1PoAf5Slt4U3SgcmtPCGRI6BjHMfT6LQCGODRekOUJFxgByr15W7FHNwjHExcIL5VyelIPKyzXgXwaUkiKcAXl1asQtiLgh5OwK9Y55XuZTI@/Q1HTc2/xZ/eRGcb/Rv16GNePSqpR656lM3yn/LKM3rrzBdDeOdKMdoOZLMufUmuFmBmqKKQFT3eP3CunQlyZzLznLIHkEyYCi4sXnBuvPtjZxlJuBadZeaQEFTJEQlfMqFK7vN87ysNy2cq8TWbcrVhRaGpdzHcmHWjEo8vVCA/EkOApOULIUilT03ipo89kvFUNG/0WGc4mxADBln3X23zvMcLWovme9rmObWXQpojNp@Xt1gb18QZmtHGF2k/QYAvVGQ7WWJPwoXcQkasvK1ecjfFC9vun2Y@sXUYByNjmy6VflcWE4g1t024@Z72a9GG3HK9orJhfL1iNZWdtP1WGavKxWV3FA60uwK3jgn1OW7tq8wkjCgDEjgSs78yPcP4oMBEipoYFkmWNVbtProuM6GnXdNpgB1Pbo4sIhR/ytPc/jIxt50ie4kYdhAeYKRiU76OH3YjHXVlyMQ@84enyA7odzih2kjuzfg8D4ldJzDud2KkPYbMJufJfKau5AZD/@zCd1Vut3849McNWrZI8xm1PId6iBBMQAKTTzc9q3sGYemRHhKmSNwVthxC8oLuWKdHk7HNxj4nGFIzFXTYFUyCFDsxJYMvqbGaoGPC1d8xCDbKU8I7vo3UIpYlLyyNNKSs7TbD02xq6mRMC/bciSdONiOoxjPT8IKudImF9oIvfkmSdxEjQLed1V6A2hVh5Rnax@p0FvT81OI06GaMo39xTcm6iPnMqSjFGimjoTwtJxnvgBXpkT@lo0DI2mTCGWXm8vm5j5FO55az1xEO8h3b4hd9FcYJ6DiBGXuGqKNeKMJyYoVKcmB4qsGW/wSh0/XPCL/xtT8GK37M5V88KDrHP33snTzKf@x9@fibw5hokWxW2YLK6ctsI7H0XKGVseimfhqrtMiEGvzYSxf42FPiw2KRgBAp5o9/Kp58KRJCH3OO86j4MScESQ0ZMCne3V4R4ItTaObSWBRzmTnnkWMGP/@i7ChaW/kvxlBeOPKXsDCbSj6mp33OsEOg2E/310txOYmKq0ulJ0vlJ7QTOgtuCsPgEuttIbo8DW5IlYiwnaWl5@NvKW5IEeLrTeSv0csb6qekNRHfk0g7KWkRqqc5t5OJ2YrqeMITVJ6ozOFS4eLixGV8XD5iw@8qYjlTlmNBiemgxX15rJ9R/wLt@BHk2qR3iHAkrAzERoSPUAuAbJKv3MahjpkuC@zn5KlNxG5lIDS8xZy1WvT6vYJW1hxvYQ1KNLxmuqul1dLkHJ2aoqkZOq@VqYUHqrz@4ul//Nver7lRbn2p@H5If0e5X3Mrqzl5pAf69dj8usqt556j2MrX3LhIe2B6fPof/5vqr/@F4ODL@Dn9s75sYK2Mc@uFKlf5kltfoYfy0hK1@3/@@Z@pD/OyY0Mu1vmmqxixNUORTb/HvEvfVQO9lG3pQiJW2DELMMTCkPbm9AOGUTdLqyU@pstpq4qrQEe@MvYoeolnw6wRmwrJSYaxpyDNSCpU0UBBQBoTio6ybDeM2QaYN0FT/fzQW4loB/CzNueIm4xNNx5GMBmal20RDWBeWqT9vDysl15kY/OOStbYlKwZFRJbOy1rVx@vETu87QejsJW2kjDT9aLlXwenHvjQC9qXtKfqRd3@L8PiFbHkRXlptdjB4X6R7biLA4ZUGIy930gR1MmAaGPIRqeuGtII9C8QwsvlbEGk0G/Hd1ImnyRp2YOgJWdY6ZzEVER8/Fy5HkZ3vESVzvO/pMAjc6ZOBGnlSvvYo5p7@xWVXYwLSjne8zrA5i0bx@oQGAWxhh2wbPIy3AecDpr@eLXhGTshcS1EXZcint9uN339LZ@Zy5pUaW5m7jzoDqrZjoR3R@xU3Jho@ouaeSuUQogThEKBBR1gXQQjn7bo1Sy/wX48aQFhUvRdaxwqLiFrR5fVu/p2lbOu3NH0tTR9TSMKLSFpJ@YZKxqbsouJbKniqHIYNHGlNrNhai0ySZuHHv8BBpEMS6MDtwTdHfaAJKol3dFWZfawubwXJh65DsRnT44WJXN1Jpc4P7qmhHhQQ3dCu540RgICUXArsFCm3wfiAVE1aUbDXkbi@U18NvE9NBjuwx5Cidph6yT4qCxLvSvkvglH7EupiAQ6rqxtg52R1SMGHYfYilPQZnHwknXAUp0Kb7a4oBmOCqeBNiGhslk5pzpuqTi9bEdnr5VEEfQiWyovPX6yvPJ09RmynM3p3s4Gg0oedgGDc59gsEadp0023ler2YWsvEIK6ukmAX0WWFzAwazr2nFM2Odr50G1XNLASlmGdc1pNKS6Pq5kkAnEYeBhRaA9Sn6YzedfVI7RsZOPbecL/Uf8beIDMsOZcLS@kN4ah7dJZKrMhQQcqLJg5qA4@ceIoOLoL3bZoN/ZR7SJALauwvbU0A4iQIzOh/3Ls3ObOzwd2uqQJgwRnONSYwf1KhglAcYsrKCL6gOHhuV9UTXwjqd7AKNcLAnQ@QQ4TTMdt9LXlqaYHQu0CCGyJjxWcYVomY7a7Mzc2eur@u7WJGI5Ow0dw/Vsy1ZS7jiSGQLIIFev1d1Doq6OdsGupFomuamoyizgSihXZnd4H77SLSSitqhiZDXrDaP8XWQpMy8moU2TqjSOwGsGzHLp26Q0fq2mFyCIEYT6NCkWYm58n2OTLMHJHmTMU/BytmLZiL4Jo4gDzOnGso62KOVCnFVgLnMLQJzblLLSkVIFI8qPdU68LKONZI7iFY2jAW2GHO9Ug5klOc0EW91GEgAbWccNLdD/xu6mq7bq9M/2@y0XivJG7a/od5zi@XZ8yxrfckU1ts0Q2NFi2eYWNlO/wkWJmKWkA8YmCEL4diQrYpBEDag3tjXtZVIfp@b2ScIVYFdfK@HmdFRPEgR64TOQOb15j0NxsLsOv6vI4dW0pIlDquhpIUdcd09siyZzSasxJCHlPUAsTYKIA7Uk3D6XMLxYoLPm7eu9i2HsxvZsnk6xrGyoSG3fLhLZ0zx7K2XuYoslzRZLFYzjXXzBfHsnb5wGnb72RYuZ4xu88eCP8Ubh/sxR@G/BHPV/DHc81tzxuALZI9wRhw1nj05Ow96fwTGnY16Dm@3wLMT5UMf6iU6UXAsACzxgCB9S@lguoW@3iBOVn/1hcXI9gpHQ0jIcA/5Q55/ozj@pQOby41bwX7Xzhb9z55d155crWGtmjLxW7axw63@fHicqYT79YubwQt2VYs4f7emK7ulKBavpjGH@/97Twv@jnj7VPX1aQcQEuXCQ8PV3c7NoIrWDzUYjMbfwMjpoVx557GdzpYO9V7uapc1Dp3sZnVehras/jP@qxn8V0oifkIYOdxGxbWi8l5ftqTjLi2bJpxwKTlbSE@mviYxu9VcvWMl@RC9QIqT5YGuoNyqkkLvyMblt8hL9MZG@8eJzX5xFtutkmbg4tzbQsiMsO8kUF81XJ8lcWonXlS2Ogaw2D/d3Fv@HkOHC/6S90Ah5DO110O2alcTegh3GUad0Z6zuAPaB3nOkWEWTk5EdaW/vmF3mbpdqHNhiYl2cvUmQqzbc/9Fe6gL6hpWVG0dGRBtP1ze7Kpjmmu2FvKG@S6HZXdY9/kNc@kxz6bOK2tcbg9tI5esDP82LyT5taXn5rjVAann4gwlYcqn8HbPq/wI)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/4hnsf)

Clostridium/CCBI are separated with the same method as RcFunge-98/cfunge in answer 366:

```
@,,,"368"z;@,,,"364";k0<
```

Answer (score 1):

## 369. Befunge-98 ([Funge++](https://github.com/cwesson/funge-plus-plus)), 16227 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $x/
# {\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'@,,,"285"z;@,,,"366";k09<          @,,,"369";@,,,"364";k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"763",,,@;z"482",,,@              @,,,"368_"z;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _'1:,,@
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6IDW2jNm17FWVfW4abu96Co19dvLo0XXfLPua5Njs0U2U1BzbnU6cg8l1@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBxaAmBPDKmVKmetBRahPY2J2l/KBgEemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2bkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGvNzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7Qk0DqYzD9CwjABaUohB/IdGZzpgznQynk4Y4NYzPb1jAdDOnPWMvj61JmnWgTAgMvmfDw3bb8wATgYQJw7H6tWUUDMWbV7v9VgG2jHgcWowE6hGaFVYNgv@zHGBahArwMgHRu2al9GYQZ1BFfWdCstnMhC@H/ogtrrlOT4yy6hhoA19leoM4T5znYGrj4AaPYNo@tnBM@Z1HRfe4IdxeX@6DUxXn7DtbRbf//RhnNXDapHdjhBWUY1dQBXEgkB2pltTaCHRmnCgftwwtYBVFt@IV1gcyKJlWC7HctBtS0zLA5HUTBkc0P@1rAq/AtNKLKdCD8rH05hP39UHpmVwKAOEUsSGr@WZBvdMjmXVEo85cKw@j9alzIosW2KFIivmWRHuZVbWIDcEnWNqOQ@/AvwAWhlQUeGXzXFAi3YP7RTb2h7r6yPTmvvQCXyX5VVWBIiArwqQtRJAgGc2i78s/Ait5SsKezIEag/1MwAvWeYpciMjZEhYhQo8lK0thTgislyevTfE7IF0QLR8iRUh@wJQIgcoAGW1EmSfz/CCeEPDsvxkQw@TEbbFDPwA8yLQoQTUzwAtM0jMIvzgHfidBoxNAy6mAWPSgJloGrizmAXEK0BYAaqy4NNrqHunkBHPR@sR8YGjAxgVqY1MTEUiAQSoLZaFOiuwHDSELDaEfJYB/oBLscCAj5VUVsqxUpEBPcsZBnWjAl7YSlTgnyrgoyIwqH8VGoAKOKlAbRWAqtk8EyLEVrMYDmmzkBZIo@YgTQ7cUHFqAX@QDlqGClmqkKemlReNEHDT8lDefJZap1aA2i1CGNBNA1w1aE4aYKuVIBzTloCGJWy8xXiaE0JHOkCtYHOHdgjEyAM@BBfiglsrZjn9dGs81DvIrXnKTh@TFrAbFJCMkDSDxYNnDqkJqGQADPYCQF@DFpAFcmSharO5MHtLBSANBG/0TGLQlgm8Sw0pVExTg3yljycLsqkFwmg8nwxDP437OcA4TWB@xkDvzsNA6H3pMHDhW8iir0a8dgEok0NfDzirM/WsBZDQkdMoK@PMtBZ@JfLrGXqvb3rDtwtcc5RJx9Antnm6yCWfT0eIqkcCChiw5FXMRuNOTAmGq8EQXYuyaEWMM3bCClpCWVUJvY7Rn9oDQyqXIvhRyGTqTmBgWeRZ5t6uORjAmLyAo6apmDRQLrzzhKGVzU6E0BOpi3m6Jgzf91h3CAJFGFjm8MvlBYyshjDmegdHdQmkMBgFyjhu9c0Z69zr0qixQDBLdOoOzXEQubI2cqRyKZNZqRBpG0S5N6VMyJrxasmvHNNOxFk8KVwJMNZwyTI6UsOA9jmOUjjuYtOFcdUhqWHBPhN2MDImgWjLgzyMuhawUaiUro4jMI5HBo2nARxzIjPIBMRAwzlDsZUGxaVsPBo4Oy5KqSDl9AzXZRgXRFsvTUOsN@14xuspylELvPowZhswtPd10woRoHFEn5AAAM@4B/nNl9Huu86IBpsRDqGW44zXiCswYJ8joMfOubFAfTGe6@OxBVIT@BtcaANkznWSt0k4j@bKEYJEmA4qHABSViBtmK7RJdr7RYfUWZBLllGsMK1@L4tQHkTEqSx0FhA1PExjTy2rAnKO0WXZutIzzhT04SLXsqiFOARCGIhSPoiODrIyYk5YhJDuaTKJdydBzXrOaLlofHw9CIs@NFEwss71OdReH4ZWY6aPQKJnKDZDz2UjaDG8BrEmQGfBYh2wnmPHJyGUcxeEWCh0WBISlJEmE3NkgPbjQBKs8RwhjaM7YdaZQ1MmauVkUnc4JtcIJQvXCcU9chEP3llA3OtNu0g1zNu0qQWBmOShjO8Cq@R@wsRlzaYOPxfkubGv4cnowIjHiFpEQfB4b/cl7y5BRBnVsD1QKzyZmah/QcsfOH1obOcmlB0YFiRdwO4SEZAEoddM7soCkRwb0OjUYibrjscM/GFQgub5KFMCEdR5ZbI3EGgNQYXoTl13zmZjqAlzBLEmXaffh9b7xhgPAQQb9Vh33oXuCZWMrUfoOcRguuPlYi7eNg2IY6NSsvfs59nAALKDwNpH7RSb/KIA4zEVgUih21yYtXWgFBahO54TWYTYIkXfcWT07zmGR43FcU/Dro@ZecaAugb0s/6CGY1QOIdWapNS0QPO43cvhI8ZCisLg1n5reBjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdJf1QcmOiLCoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXZm2hF5//ARyvvkK/nAZG8obN5n29daDUQNW05ElkX9B1Ef@2qIjrzW1@QlEjxClZNzFmt@I3uIcXYtd/ElxlnC4KW4BocxdQlUfohJTCfISpA7mt0h8sIJchuSt6G3udObxQe/aPbuiEn9MG/ERgW2I8hK6IV4rIchwc@6CUgeWwirvuSBUZc87gCte6MVkJ0QSasX9ZUVXQameBfQkWM7K6ACMUO4GGU5hOqCGuMxcg3dChsjdRdvqY6QYS8ml3AggzF0PHZc6Bmc6cxpJoGqLNK6fAU8EY4VSZk9WB5aYciI44A/wVEQEowtHdoCdjHsqaBZ6cApgIlxBRl4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidE@vnjQnGUts2UDnT3TkHAsWD4RkymjPTdYENnuEgwcegYDCRqZ3CmKD3eshZkRzU769nLmOL3pt2zNl1LbyLnvIrTzjTXdZHBdwFoQM6USLe9@LJKvlTykiQqDjjiUJJ@V2EiBRJhipP9EGnh0HiETCa47ndTYhLXUxMM3E66ZfEJDgwIZfR2CegKlzHDtUHbDSjU@jX9FZlAxi@JQnuEvoRJhigyBiguyBnQCcELbNc7nV0dgncw2XSbI@rIoFKosq5MC/D7oV5@YRAXKLllXkWntslhxQZ1bAEGJ1KToPEEgHfkxKUUAQPRfHHVvQgaY@HkVzDPac2zcOxBBdFkuwiFH5hAEgQMiYIH2bXnLR9ceXevUBw2ajVoLGBNAVss5eMarTBhKUMnBoiyySN@JnIE@d4gn0jkYTyYuQrjg2ITdBSa3V2MRm60OPo/UqASEBWwcaWHBDWr@dPzdNp73pF2@iJkUTsdSA0md2JWBVg8Oe9oXYbVeNLVAWtN45UxcaL6Qn0jcZLvlihoh/NNTwUf2s@KpEaTiAGfltdSSKe1PdbNOi9edfyRQLugs7OuVEH0D/1J7JCRpT2ZYKg097oqRwIdgcOhz3bPXlc8/siD1Q6pl1Z8rCcrm6R9yZGF4O0Tw4eHO0e/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@GH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8/Doa9dJApIQkoNyADf@rok0PA4IXUJH94bXBmE2SKUgyzBJEJdJByyAGToQdQzXA3yeTd@8wcq7jtTY90fMrKnOAQSeyoEdpJMx8JoAFgR1@nxEpLQghZo2LjQsXNGYAT4fo9R8HRkSpSNN5uPDR/tHNQLrz6tJFEXxJiBL6W5PhjZvTUEFXxUH2B@4uiwlLxBHeZpwXUngbneJwIu6ZWvgAwDUdWSHSdYoKJo3BNz3rpeNfKVu2ALonSBclyuj8lD3QxGN4IFDXBdV3lWjKAUsBqvQa@WIFYYuD1vdfN4o5srRYau7yLMXBUqLAjAOBHKjC0GnnoQ@8kKK9MVqH/3jJzcQ90iIBFVACjDzLCZTXp4loPYimSzuKXugoTmWIX9OHE9kYlJR4sG6gNz1SPmMxN@fmZNEJsmfahLiQu67uwfawyCyP2VNMxmkNKAujiOT28f1va4HbcR2LGfgsC1Iw6XDIEMQm9YWc3fg2DdqSEdPLGoMlwiB/@LEjT6GscZ8Q4ojpYqqq3yxUbe9c@DSaiGLRCIKESiF4suv9DMdyLUo9/HBN/ZhEFHzmUzoztAFJIikIXKhqxvxJQ8mQUayj8/KAobLhTd6exAgRdbrsNA@owsT7i6CV3oSx5SVlfFXovSJc4Pir5z5taYFPrxpgSNCsoNPnz05@HT/6e4XzYmWzy@95zLlAhAO8uuALCQPOd2wt27xronFQnAx6Bsudi/gAlNQUILVoqnnAuOWMYrMEVjTavhCa@ITZ2jHveT1wpxjqPTK7vIm9BQ7H4/qJwRFu2ehMuLy1Wocz7H9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedV1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQpAxpsbPAWf3ALRYU4ziLo1ckB5oTVvZA0swcHTrJVlDoagC@PCuOEm5bAFU2mUHmgIoCsrYdmIAdMb0NZ/BvUk8qb9VVUr8XatZrScIgbRlro/xN3oG6A6JWC0AlIkr72y5r3mPTYHLo2QrgOJMXmLJjk8hmOBxUCQpFlT1PMD4hC3wPlS5BVEo9dTnM0FLqXkM7miWsgroJaBmgYyq4RzbtJIn3SH0sSRAJ7k9GneINIK@15Xt/vylu8IkAW57yMoarbxotm0WyCgN@8Rbrju3Ji3GmorWWU3k2z58ZNVaL1LxcO2G3hA2yUnNE16sjX8rKffZGc9nXpXjymT0dgfc6Qxe7oLgtQbB/h1z4j2PUygRAOVraW4CkZ@q6yYELIwqYA3pJQCHQpGWmh6CuIlgdCL4iG0HOBbkQRsMZvBy8H3d0T4CCrd2O5NJ@7RGgnKNThb6o2BiDTZ3EUu7eH84ARGx7DlI5eGykUmzc6NOM6j6x6frYRE/hp/kB50tRACzcqHM9J2uKsBGgGlIvUcOAe0K5w2HS5mGVHph5YGGRJOOPkAEoRNqwcD4DOQmBdklxeE50Q@y0U6tZ1zG6F1DFaSOuaET/Y7UxfXus1etGwQPavxOACNChfh67Qo3jG6fJaVJ6ZSgBKos5ExcnAqAaQrYgUGFUHnC@qoC3o4Yw3dKiPhiiHAl9j9PeBiXYPPF0kjVKKgSe2z@MRVdqVvKLr0BlrzLbIVFj5SxX6lnwQEWN7eQLMk/gwoSSfOiCJ9TvMtGPggEHcFXDGEEkMLE/WaMzbs6zof1wgTySptQ4jH@SLQRXxjYyNeidfjaXDtgGsbXTvoSoFrh1wSuTCejC5KkSYXhjYoBfq14leNAPIs2cI2MEPJ4Y05TuiNSiXbSusN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6Ewmxfo5rtmA/B4p@x62neOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9nSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt50eylmlfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXL0qQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRI3MGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/YYxHs7daIRw1g2kbJxBX@xVwS09yMWjXPINTx8V6JY0/UDu5fFAuMXJO5SXxnPO3QWOaVNZ2hkVjLtnUn/kTHTlMxmUJjkyXMY34ookwUhIIRwSFfup6WEX1m3DmXrRmcaVE6CYO/ieDKfALIPtaWloVeZYMLpDh8U37wN0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16QOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8ZDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSQ5MnqCBfyjD@xR5nXhGj1lS6BVWscdwggBpUFOrIW1NfIDFMcb9@TJDJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh85z1NE0rdPP9ShCGrQKIPYRKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzPp4UCHf3Tw4f7fO6EBlscXnEerT1yelOQK3296ciwB2m2D@3JtJ2RCWQI0r85tY4cZ8K1fHhZNzPDlWZzNLV0mvO5Pi1za7qu03Esmgq6Leki/tT1dEvnk1BB6O5nT0HWf35yXJMrkUiKfja6NW@ch1ydLafnQXTNkdZbg@UhjzdMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDoK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjgusL1QNfI/m/T7S95Z8j6VkDVZC@8cefO9oEs6YhSlPI@EG0OX4kQBFShOuD90bbwixeO7W@RwZfFpuAlhaFjB0uIRSCy4fAaDvoVyFSgtKKLzPZwGSNhjXCUh1o1rb6wLQqh3Yz4DOttY4rGF2AZ1IBjcFBRphE2F@XPfVepCtuOvWXqcrTqg89O0ynadr3KjTuVydU7hs/KbbQCxXa8GG@7WRcOc4vEwGkEl3CAFFZMW9m8UNdym4dFku0BJqoKngDox0zJSc1bcb13GFY/I0Gdiszn7KKN9AXoJ7pbcvKcMjCrtcVpDr2oQEvdl2M6cSSDxYSw@cd0dAp9hqdkyKaF@pnbfsXoSXyWDBsO4foUV5G9SCHdx@pt1DdMNNnDSDlqeFPlrZO/nDbjXqrR@M0Jkt2gICLrPBbs8TZ9dsgYMeWeyN7bMSYtdyROnPfR3StnX95VyGdR19bkn@Htcamz36OPPGpkWhyCMdFz5KvFanAXbk0FwBkEJ95GDC3fqTMwJSQK0E8HE8qoyIDWjRRJAH2DwDKoszMgvEaJ@aVwuytI3QFNNGIi5Nx@lmZG8kvuWPpkYNm9zfPlxPbn5OpGfTY2y3/EXHSosQyszIJmaGAYoVtnxycP9oyMZWq6XiO/jCk4FuqPeHYKAsq7QASWjha@wj3px9hGmSaLaLkBXA@2j7aeHRl2FRg/6B@SOvGNguAnwTOLiSxe8ab2LEnIJzScQ7rfqTohGIbCEkYQyEbDKSvyf21zV8vGsQItPESWB3Il7FaCtmZSntvla9mCgIbkVosS5sgrjRW0zQVxsU036G@pGuHQMGhYJjVCCRoNJb4DLQWSRtVpVvgcA4qIC5g6QuqJIVUG72GtqUPU18AaRhiD4yWtv2YtGRiq3UpurQNHmMn8DOi9/BC5CWAbtGSuz3UxQf7/RkTkOfC2Qc@7npE5fO31RYZvcIfI5Z4oebJgipkP7q5b3SS3vwoJOhqyEpmKwIAFLiPnHA/w2S@HE@UHnwWTkkUiyi5DoGpKcXV4SDdmmxoiG4FIZr4yrQPsExvTEgdI88Y8GRKUD6q3@RhLss01BDNSs5ZVaDOEivHJ2TTqVzsRoOi4dmvapQ@s9oaudkdU8SoRh6tGpdTMlbkKl21LUEAceV1uHnTfq9Om2IgIte/gL6uRBE@q@LAxCpK4c0YPm1lfkvLyJZClbf3sqjbTgZtLrO2JK5RJF7nc65rqoQATcFxY8V0QDJoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHFx7WVR9Ov7j9gS3f19tP7zP3@zB/S/WTtDGChw5jF0tGHoxpqS@msry0@KL3RbXbF8gnxqmToRhlx3gezqLhRJt0LHatC0CC9JMPyPcEnBr3Fom3gDqfGWZsYx5yuCwXN1JqsW1Wxgmd11ca/tx@JZ0fIPKHY9IgIXgkyDEhHr4pVgzPgSTETFRjZ2N1LBpilGjZnX@3A6mfI7CK53VqI5xt9tfdOPmcnrHdVQ@M71W6rc1U@nPUcanw5CObWwIu6i9LQGLIE44C8Ht9G5uvi8gHwnePBcF20xtCnn9LirVXj21BtLHdLCe/yNOsLolhxci9/XRTH9w3uhYz3VTItu79kSfejQUPzdEAruNZUiRDOvkdnSO3OUQYYf3srCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldTo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WOWoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatjRwHpO7U0t2F65YmvsAjWEZYNyPtDxvPzK4D4sCYqUVZ1YKhIzJgEMsMtsYtMsLtxHSLbH8wV5ExOE4iha7VLMDpTnDL6Jo29R4MjW/VxA2xkUYiO@so1XXO8bdWfBiCasrvq0e0Nyuxeg/mJFldS4dxfO1wsDQ5iJOPdzTUc9Mz6LaasKcrEZ10rZX@y10gmPaLTuPd1aw903I8dkz32wg0cIEK/L66QUdpaeq2RJPhUfctPCjY47CoUN0aOFahNFB0uK2t9anbR77vP9@Xw4UcSlXv4FCB@OPYqv9cy9dPFff0rgqiA4su7m@NOG8ZYlexKX/tZX3pQDHAhbvVJXuUKVFKWeFTfWsyxiWXc30ePH@GoWMdaYOhYzwncRqkO0xQLoFj4nIR@2fJLXd7br33Y0o3wBbvKkSkck8tAwYrut@oUqZl1A9MoWYy78@i@tbUmBorFY3DzisDj9XfomS8P1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1htfM3wvrHGcxrdbmYlumV3jblFmmamNQfoeo@r8DBzP0HEzxcCejpdqdUk7s49uJ9lwHHRpp7eEHYZ8KB8q3SEpLcnnnkG/WzUmruHhBrFaPpPJ@AJMZMVl6eU2TSobpn1l8vtSxuSzyHkRF1fZ3IhzdR5ElugWxLUsSFun2FPkclmxTduYzPH@nty04zjWh9QUMFU8MOyAtirRVtvbauyGuOMfImGLqQsPJzw6/XWTFny08XVLoA8qzbdVenRJ6L1qU8JFzxEuSC2/3j59E1lguisXPNyKc0J88621Xpb0Z0NUuSQXb@11XEJ1Ooal88eskLsNXlnO3gpvmWn4i7W4uMuXdBdL8bFrTGk8B2KZPdBShsbIoNdbpHy9hyYy/MfaSDMHf@uCZ4bRVWb7RnddhLEJfMHG@9IackRYmjg26FcT3OeHeoqFO0l933UcOFj1W0nkg5E@MLjNlts45WLCAnfTcLVu4Vw9dVHhO2i6kGxhjGN9k4BOdWrMveC5EuDTeRfqdTq6e7rtWufv4hzoe/T2dVtYbw6x9tAZ2kNjyPeNh2/rOge0xwm3sXMb6oD1YIhb2cbjpS3uUXpajmW9Dz2RNXJG6Tj9lTjt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PlAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjfOWbQycTndo3oW0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a5IGZNJD9FbtkwgrzuXsb3UouHH@DhYV@n@7BEf1kLHLfLKqhk6OpYtjfXTrsdnQ9HFKjghHOmN/PB2hY6/V15PzckCaGQvUzi9y5cl0LEOd3/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tibSslIR0FcsnIgMCjrst2eZ9bpItls/y2DqFoKQmjyL6UDyG3v/eHZgfNyLwt@C@1r6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491ZNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBVTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohp818tTLtV0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr6wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a65oFdRkV20vuhP216e6Z359CiVb19jQYgNfhnSjR/vxbQW8p/rA7D5eqogQSZ/A/k5P/lhq/uh1sy7Oh6aHO5pCxy0TU9jkeCPGVtcGvWFFzOvz9qGxikUH4scgV8ZeNbfujOd4WmxOrtum1c0JzbL6z3Wq47pNYLcicT4djaee/1iNA@2Zis5Cj07J3zs3Abj0GlgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFaQwf1BcONdJ498wLWfAvlHKMBDaQAhD4XxFw3kAw/Mz3JDj2itaIuX9nsueONEhubxgr6FujSyTTNuc3D6bM5ng5pzgiYXhIweeUFCe4F2@/6EQpJPVFHlyt6y/OJp8x/gOLe/YmbpdA52hvZGoWuDnauwFu4/xRIeD9lLOo1pa17Gge4HDWtlluo49nUju1L51VCjcOipU0NpUpBmwxNf3nz5PRlsD7da@SwoN7JEtXGs3DFxrZKYNgth6ProcO9AlHnI7SUe0VfiONLtozKlL7Pqhs0rfeTaHAeS9FSZg/tPRQ6OLy4Z35v2p89SxHRiNxsAoR0cGP/O/tNFjdUJM9gRPtQN9endmc0xg1wxCXNrQx0YH6tdauN5nLOKAH@oTfc1QRHODpP@Frjvbiml1DPcVTfpF3OtU2mWEHhsz0i3WNxjeB6VJt8tFYpyPW@ojSys23thxbH4nbpuBh/r0dq4CQwHd3n@hXMaN@EvzAiv1s@WiHp7xXSJGjxulWFdW1@g4Fr/fsifJNvmeAN01DU95gjYOyK@QYxJIX96tPKR4Kw9ZqEYgyZ7pHi3Sr1Y1FiDV2QdsARrqbtfBlTDfccvunIhhgjvYdLi3n28c6ADhZ8Cx9O7UNxZ6F1rWqDOi21qFIVKbR0YHTwV1yJrHRJ/drEw@M@SbMojs6AoNAATsCjt1gSWegTaSvHvYWtKjlqlqjulGnHrtcjlt1pFs0@i@0XHWzCF6Leaml8KhzMqn5FwzVx3pRjSLrOh00n1lT1reugYCjWVIk6ELOr8yuW16OzCzsmI9ZDoycJF5eRVmrejqeEMqrLN6PT1krq4h@bb@gJeEdv@4fCjtrpU8ETz8Hz74RIFBuF3IBaZHgHXdvYIPyE9d23@8Twt85niTvjk7BLzxFMA6doLFykMSePCega6tdYWA2rOnFp99GET2XY16pI5JZIVZkixi1xNDMuwziQzBzW6WyOGHvpRdtN47MXqSbwcBVxqkJ8H5rzCa/1yxgBrljbjZU1U4YWeFnL/9cxVxzwPOAPKWM5HGHj2Vsffs4MnhiTz21JXj0@4QT0fckOOWDCtopUxkSuqV7kbWO/l2tJ7pTZQHx6q09@RAxghr6M1XNCR44Mrc0mPtvGdgxVXR12pBGGpMVguIj0@ePkktjmiyxN7QdUZGMhq8d3ycxpMmnxyvDI6mfgS9o@/M1iY/2FfV5Irm@9ym1cF13HNFTusgnRigjUJjfMztstwpXHWdsdE7mY@Nz2DwRA7uvWf2hbWF/FQ/MwfYC1l5LaGoo7KyXMglIzuzQdk23PC5rj5PzTFyyy49FP5Yux0FJYes4mZXSw@3rfhfl2JYxt@J8GGJ1MzN1hq1I6zo3t8XMVVV19H5WO9DvbL82spajrBqfdhyzt5jKdnwlRcp9JIm0Kok88595EVpBKxbwRtOz/ue4Oys3QZzG4DQu7Cyw58b9ly3JVrLuk28qEBq3NR2a5RvGO@xIBXu8DlDY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8o6MT9xIkr29Bwd3JTjyaXl7rI8/fc6e6R4aIbk9YhRj4z0wXkhGrySct0ILeGuXU3sugNJuhTcYr@7PFXasuz3Hns/uXoSjM6g4tJNx4RAWvlEkwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6t3mZ0V978EIczX5KDo8ZpfEDvvv3PVDWTIdND@FQz/PWOmgk6OEugS5@jPbto0MlByBq6KLfI4JFcqY0@MWa4HYXPBq9S6leOb4Vbxr5icv1wcltY6Zaw3C353QhDT5aVM@otAPO3hLG8HAY/cazzoSPv6a7hrdh/vBKh2wpSvqUg5Qh39q2l08Ki714v4uPRBf@xsrWeGBM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyZ6isfSb4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c@NVZm9FR/szqAOM3pyiBggsZwSkcibgYvL5B2QOY17IHJ7SuyB85kn95uUczCE8@r9yKY44fT8XqMgTfiJymus/OliJ@Dzuyce@wBHo1biOkrdH/cH7faf51My8KJQTQz@vhkN2hdh8eKFslxgcUXz5a88fDo5PA44ucas9k6pVeardMhV4Yscv30JLeU7Xb9xdkKYq0/bwTiBvDj8LlWDuLM7pPjmywB1bfhZGQFIZ/o9mLGdKnCes6EThquDHw2n9E2ypU1PeS72FaFud0V3kuKPQzIpgl5e0q7jZb12@11rfLE@ILWHkAMYhMulnCgvuElY5YbBhhSkrUd1TldCD9L6B6Ph6Y9Wxk0WpeGdpEmXnmru8EuO7acc/YktCq0jj1oq4HrZ4a9jjmtOqwolbO3S2HZayLVunrhXy/xH@uq5ME6Qe0az8ANEbdxE0x/1FUeBS@fack7439yHES/O@6e5eD8fc@cju6OTGBTqRUR@YldqPCotXcv7dvr4Sfc@bliTw5M8icSNsBKLn//KHpIGm0iJzbRJugmHYiGuJeXbMM/hAwBYnCs2T92jaYDTXtq4Llp/lWUSW0TsqnV1HyZ7eAHhyqg8iQpR/QiA21BXg22eeGfKK5U1Cu2UWNiRWT@me7Q3jK3GQxw0doplIlJpyrbnEDIZnAemdHnL9glo2kU0NvUfAbeZCVqmaHqn9gGlDYvnh082z8@2T15ftzItK78E91BIWwbcgvsRnyU7YlQdp9sIJ5xC@JkScCC7OjTHDj94gXlYvi5n@Wi1ZaKtiiUuINpNi9sW1HoULsiXQF@kshzo1BkMuDFYQclpvrx7RlU@PlyOiYPVcRBi5Qn1FmFZVZlPNZB1Ni0/fDrX8eiUPx6WgW/n4YZ@0afoSEOHKfn5@gZ7O4ryPHR7sGT50f7LEBw0WjOzd5kWCvnuU1wbmgD6qlv0i6/Gov7SeJQV7Va/FEcCBOX46xCZgjIHje0c4gWUAcNGPipt1hik@ADBeNhpSj/@ZvKVVzGDetJiBsPkIpDttDkqaFsbGywE2gk7OHRwWf7Rwzx339I3kgiBMFO8Az0n/2ox79oEdgoCr4c545ILiAbL0LUDkJgHGBhvwBpTl13vP77cfQFCbISEH66Ivz2jiDQl02g3Z6TecFrpueSZA2Kf@/OtwwYZERNKLCCj2sjaOXP9diZ6ZloowBx6KPRveXGjtupyNCkzHbx43j4CT6dPq8CqE/tCTds5Zu3iUFLk0OWk2abhCz/GIsYiRjf3oDG3jFAZGSebYIAMqmwV9AScf2hwm1YSFI9fiNJALpCLgnFjEjEG1b6PKXpKu9@9Z8ogyoD9wTc3/Hds8wDePtl/60P7l/h7hcKNrSbVv0WuEQRQkucfgk4IiH9kfaRbwLa3G7IgnBofDDgq8wcQTWdEdUxOs@B3yVgxws4icZnUGnQ3KDGfHshPD/DbSXQFGhFUbBJoRoj02kNY8a3Tl4zCVrIF3KqAkhKZwFAsuE/wDPhHGAyWYFuIpyZ49pLEI23t7eZiHMZRq1Q5TWrbNovsuLLENFNiCucDxG5BoM0kGSRAsLqfjIYfFJqEpMi94qrcWRcPQdGJQrH0QvfbZ8QIksAsTiNDDQKP8PPR05ghPdN23bwg4uR77ts@oAkFcYkciVFwbe08akzgeYDnXTxBSduaQO3DvMREG1GevyjqmRRFtujfLNnLQ6IBx@S8fuajDyAg8pmrg@m0boVP0cQxwiiIq5qvo0XrDlp2i2Ft00GzfSHKxqzDe5fUgZr2iwv9@5Ne6KJ69ZAkVjs/rHt4KTNIygMS2iKllXUQnJRpFxuZZH8EvnZQHHQaNElZAdsClhG1zBfOWNvd2//4JPDZ8c3bGZSzPj1aMD369uppiSnG63QEY8Wa7lKHjxSjp8@eBRUxALpQoQbA@P3S6LeVpLFXCyCXJztuV60VRheL916jD/np/@v45vVbkONEt3AQ818QL60v156RKfkrmeulVZRK5@/DaUFPCUCeo8fcb6BaiJ5cdVobdebdix@syWs6AgvYvIWdgJwNb2tTQUb@83CYcHCzx2f4IfkvGhfzK7ui@JmFk2yoYWFiXO6MFrne0QCIuUNsgEWKchKEHVt7zvkMvrCtKLGP8fMbblFLVVFEC5kbqN4BNRJ8GVn5CILw7C@TdQhKPuW2RECC2HcNmpgwjE0i8qteyWSgv95EZ5xwv/W86wyk2kzXSKJ3I5gpdltZlYDeEkBOjRKd8@moM8@c8bc3DxtmnhoBK4jB9jvwymfZDHYJ9MRxOvT48igBSzg3BIkBkrGQ1S5LAVcwreyOkuhHVvIr4G2Vv2Cy6NePjFLykNj1jMHwNsTyTRwtI9UtcVCS6xYaLK8asdFqrNFLdzaFT/Gg@tRsn@QOd7ZAgG9ocum3TNmifh5PFlpQf7oHz///CyeFFe1JTIL7NvJ7V23DxyiX1Rv5yT6xO@dgfHdVdyiXL7JJcDvOmBupy741lW5LA89gb5dWEPJ/XjiPgEniBGJ/kgfs8TU5jb@ZEaviWbCTpPxM6nO7YfaLJUihQoeFCAzStknFx@/E7o9Zwmlhp@3BF/P7uHjjTlmDVWWW@CmTJJsE79BtwcSF1q9TAqgA0OSCoGtYRMCNQMw4p1E5g0c0mA4xIUHWUpcEUyf5KJ5fgdpQqVm9Xss8k3BZclRLJcrfoUuc8Uyg9Z3kx3KCoC9wecCuR6o65v/AZqB@isLsQUjv8nxYpRvjCPy2LcbBOjEIjZ/A3NCDGAtLPJ2hy7@Evs29BWQDyqV5yeP2qWkIrLQ/tDANXu4DsXN1ocqnv@hIeimylLUeJVrdB9jMrT02OYGjtDg4CPqMOI1lhqLkuH6F@wXbVNVb231fkK/FiBmDgcA/5xmOwCH1jmDCaoVYauZ/U9/GkNhI7Gpqqdt9ywVz2eqcFOreZZnH202JWmzkand39RBi5q8njVBJ1e2cg/PjGG/dzBQmqLIsiynKFsXFxfxR1vPzBd5VpB6plZ4PZtfZQvZ17OrrFp6fTpWCw359awllmrp0xZ79uyLt@23SXF2Nn8tNhNabO/wUlRzqPLHKmV2sVPIxk7LoH5CvoydsjdwnfYZ/pP7TS/i1tHd6YMKGxdZrNnED9yLRVFRGvEW/JO6/xIurvg36nJd3mm9fZts6PpkNmemaY69Xg9@zhAkSC15zEBfvgecnidQWJOepEHhNZr1b84n5Bmb7RqDwXRfr2t4hFe@367OzemjydNvfB5cz/F6cxRJ9sb/6G0qlZCkxop5ikpbz8fw87l/9uONq/TFs/b2n31rpBgb@DjEx3eunqL7WM1/tLHx0YMHuVxa0zTufvaNZz@/u7ube5jOP2vkd3JSZmP7T/9kY0PTtjVlo@V5aiveOD39QtQyOVH@s9@Jt589@7rn1bP/5zff1lW8FeF2xorAJ@DKMhWceC/BT0UZ632v2JsYtHI1Nqe/dizwv9hgan2n@F@@d/g6NonVNeVzF56T2OtYoRTjTnDAWzZ4O4vVY9sYrXAVmyu1Wg2cxf/ybyF9/ROAgyHzbbjV8wGswjxWl2qU5DJWL4BD1TTI9//@5jcjGHI2USMxLrjuswZcYq6oiTstuLbo2hbQrqOUUZQgnj0ZTgyHqaV76j18MeEFHraBBvKNSTOGHxBnh/cZO2qkUqmW3Jbgkl/QJJGiqlpTVe8BO5A@2qrVpC3GLVdms/l7aH07SVNaAwdGTOPe5/8QV2yVZ/VnBnckxAob918@rNehTNl6dqueosvvSNSniiXRce6LLM1exkEFabRePmHc3G5dzJQ0MZ1O32/T@wxpJc3CloQXv8dioQ92WXbdbykJRPF9Yx8eL7aP15//b3/@/T//Hv19n37/AQ1f2j2zr2xBpDPoEnW47lcq3XpdrLviRRPf69COMpVSpaS0r5qJLeBArSOmZj6@jOez8WP@cW@VsWaSUsNF2db97PG9Hlt417lPPernB/DI5MH8UpBjiWrkDql2Ix4Mrf4WYalxVm9JKBDVpIZayLcknqoeXGXWuA/VJGrFstiqa3ntkN1vz/jFhpsec2KgGRYCOvr41hdlq4chi7d61CtWD5LVF3E@NF6IrxBrNJSWQQNC4Mfub1Q2SpVCRVPa9fUXNM3oK0U1DOOZFzuLhRenbGxB0FjYNK/7BVURvrCgBbMPiQeS0fswX6qlbEEVq75LazOxCo1Ey0raoC1mVDHsbTi/D9cG/NE/XOEr3jfIx/emKDevDVZRt7Sskv@osK/h@HrHFcVVgHGCdTudzptuB6QOXe/oXV2d6FN9ps/1SWfamXUm3WmXYZdZntHPOnmn5MwYb4CyFMvm1c3YPWrUbxsb7IhzoRZLBVczdef1XJbbvpMcDv4kyZnFhNg/wFVXNZVtwfiUgRsIZeQEnRn/VFVgMRC0Llpvtxpvt6CD1lPbxBxbdcnHEh5y@34rJV1dNcBdrfr/2/XQWaWLu6BwratUavtFHaSPF/VGCkC@8EHKEiOgcrve2qaQMDM/Nz94uwXyi5TabmzXnD36ydRBpHjOiRec@y0AvL2E7P37KRlc9wFAfRP6YzKV2pSkDRwbG/5YAZFb9VRQKsQhAdLCxcXP@ANFD3rx1fZV/aqxfXW1vQ3/23S/8p/ge7V9458ei2tNnEV4C1lLs6HUm0rTZxYteJeVOvrIShMcdXhCvEZWK7Ua6IBLbv23@S@nF/fQB1FuyYC1ENtiWzE0w5iNbQmxl@@@/F/w13z35e@jvMjgz6gIsQvs1soWaptlrnTCjdlPbfaUXza48Re8og96PK2jp81vNi5IKcpLmVX4nH9CLRWSMg7AbaffRssOMnsJUW/wPiZqpYLYTqlzjcW2xUKR2N3P3bji8fg/eqmVi3E@UYOmCV56nvc0guUCT4hc1TKqpF7WufV9/qGUn1t1/aOfW3cJscsyMypAn67HOGWEGDSkmKJIEoxY9e0Rbl7HtRIJ1dKz2hfS810J51H0Ca2EdfkcQe1gv1Yu1/kyz@Yz6jZbD7fgrsL//gaUgzX7ELfZr3VHIAE3@9m81kRb7TGp8xr/nrzBP3bSxb@j1/jHTt7g39EE/9jTDv6dvMa/3Q7@nYzw78Fr/Hv6Bv@eD/Cv@ZVsVq2KmxdEmpRaVq82ZyKRqBrbqTe/MnHnFcuwG2av5X@GKJsrs2Ss@RVjhh@jr3DPfvwn3/3Wt@K1WlyK08ddcqrjMjVZBepDibx49X5ciNXYprqpZqxMN6N21A44TJZxWWaYGao9UFTaKssYLDPPzFlm5Kg9cBnwlwGXmemzzIBl7IwNESEUXJN2ZoKuPjwG8NcHQC78mbgXs6NmugwyslBoo@9CInhwXbabQoPFmfjSAF1TVuWMXDBb@DWdhvjyZVPZamnlEpOxUcntxstmvCU2RbSwrpVzrDM3NpovRRiaMyJvfOjDYp4HCmw1pjSbCicTUICoeHXVbu9/@rDdVnAYaj51Dhf/h4ej6Out/6ND5@mhM3Lg//DwELqOUU/dTwGDvn@/Bgzbf@zE6tWdZoXYfsD6Y8r2TrOeldBdSAE319Av9YHXAiI86xtNIX6eQN3jHNWP6ufn1bMquc@DV3C0q4sIQTTu8J9wncMQF6gj53CdnaOD3tB5/nkzdHGH8vk5eH3OQO8K/0HBi77@V/g3/9v6f/qcJVmi0UomLq62E3Ql8S@ZvLi6uPLv9WQi4b8ktuEPPeAdk1xc1dFJkS7A1UgkW8mrK@4H90RymwOsQzbbdUq7iAfDQizMkrLlt8R/3Sdk7V/NeBXkXq5b5zPUj2JilemLfTXN5iyTSVY7wccjcJVYv6TNC8kqfTlws9NQW3/6O/SBkJ0kRcrnqlV1i/EXLadVq7ngrViqVkvBy2YiUb551TM7agH0j1wumaxW4WUnAJuBV0jbYG9TrMaacG/du8czKWmXlwHMbK6QyqgZTB3klIdsDU/v@gz34uCQvq0BrCYfw4/acFaSyNCXefDrb3GxIt67l/C/Kr@zm7x3TytnLi9Dn/EYvNQlr3a7Z7rtNvpnLy/Ftkj7YMp5eM@ULi/VTDmlxpOOm/gUPxsIWSUklX2k1SnXMrBxLVeEYB@B/PZ2IVevF3LgUyjFk7im3kD0W4BvXIxXxdgFlUEtFTkHFKvoHd0fBH0ZBwV2cRWjCmW5fDIBjDQJMuBVDP9c5Ll8uMnnk0CZK5HHVMtlHjXJcoVEKVX2/2oboJWDkMP/UFLLpnJbxa37IPPinzdbdSFPrl4YNfWqdmFUcFb9qtr1P8CM9imMe/eyZSBRKVNtCu32w92T3Xa7JooiCkpwQ0/i7gKa7XDjDSp5vtziFKlU71M1q6U8g/rkcaQ4jBCsBERXtK28WkIiCWYfzc8ASQSuLW2wDUGjJ96EMqfcBniCOgOZ9@BiPdZhA7zYAJU3ZjKLLmYxHk73bjeM5PDLDw1fKS3pd4GPEV6C3wuzvInCIP7sye7e/kla25ZYTHu0u5fWjp8/iKn4ml@8U3AW34/2dx8ePocEz57s7x7vf3zw2f7zZ@DvsfPFFTB9/754Rl0r3s/Z58Ir941uGLoxNYz2@XR6/pq9Ms22CZVpTaFQzsBlntGGsoz1Rbmq8Ouanv7qle6O6WLvfvjtdz/879799nff/fa33/3293/y5fe/Db8fwe@7/Pndf1PO4/0nX/6z3333W78Nnv8Bfn8Evx//5Mtf/yb/0fsfw@8/Rfz@2P9F4vGfALB@@Sdffu93fvLlr/wAfv/S//3g5u9Xf7z69/1fWP/DdN/73dvjfPffwu/3OKwg7nd/i/vh80b83@LxfuUH7/7Fv@P/f@r/ofO33/2LP8ab//JPf/Cn/@ndt/69ppX@9F@/@4XvvfuFb737he@8@4V/rL379X@tZqK33333/T/4qz/8vb/6w/@R/n9E9997n/93P/inf/G//sX//hd/6P9@DL9/B64f/8W/h67yt3/wQ/z/3h/87R/9EP//53/1t3/wa3/7y/8TOX6DO/6ff/lv@P2vf/U//s1vfuevfvzNv/m1H//Nb/zBX/0fv/J//fp//Ov//vf/@p98Cz1/48d/9Ue//Jff@vZf/sI//8tvfbnm/u1b71@@h/@X/wA@74/n@8B5n3J9qM@XPxM@fx9qLHKBdgKt@5fe/fovQgP/F4y9@/aP8GQX/Nb8/0hTKc6P@Nv/BxzazTJjSAZc8Pu1d9/@LpLofwASwX9Ir@@EL0sh/OU7ixcg62@uSPRLP/nyn/8OvcWMSp1WbXDsLmml1BboN1vlsj9@@ws6kOQXl6GFAPycvoMcainsO8jb3v3wm@9@5x@/@@FvvPvhL@PgLeXK6d20pN6xGgYR8@8RDyMW3iceRvwC80/RFJuU@gLe2Bd@4BdffCG0LxU8Qnj/Eny/IC9@MR6ERwz9oCAM/fHMIbtkUbfvzPjOTd83zJmxxsuXLVxvBT/MPUWyx1YgGuWzbJbyEZsxvqyD/hBptkXOGd7JF4NnAt4W/wvnTGCpmT/dC8/UwkkOP52fBXcKecgmNQsXk0hWY1w62uI@tE5M@ebKDEswm6VmoASDA3JIQdADEMdrtRQmrHF84JWjVi8xQiWVqkG5MTVPk26XEMTsAUGBlLXUEWtv1WY8YQrh1QNypAT0OhJVTUyVag8hw9rsIUNYCJzAvnxZq5dqszqCe8vpkZqlHhBOCKyWmtXfwnuNYEI6IfbwLaBSqqVS9RJmiIXk1ZNu80rKU@Go7CmW8usAnrjdf@c@Yx@JaknkiwQbSDAeG@@pRWyMCNEhvJna8otD/4GTfltE8A3Kys@F8fAdkk13uLiKEQCuJMmyzOCH6@877D4EzzioFGULjxSHkKIWQS0g9GA4P5QSUlS/KXqB/GO1rQ@@EBgWZnNzU4jVxax4KBPpFIW5pxU6@4DbAVG9qDCxUBbR26CDIAEukL5K@W/GcWEtzjhg9lGK/@7f32IfQTHpufATmJTKOjknxqFsp1KiBvDrTkp4AWqJAO2UAF0K8qxGC3kpIZ1mTK7FMIwdHh76SJDHi5qQgmauZVV8x@Wk6XQagxSynJbTaf8p05M8ZN8hU6j/lDeRuPRdbaZpuSpoT1WGXiyq6qigAqPn27dvoVZof1XlAJRP5m@10nIlCgQPbknFsubBgSEtVxa4Zs7UQo6xBE2xwpVkSYEl2FZS4LvyORLBlYhrpVKc4gH15cRWsPOuoFJzwOnVWB0RDS6uEpbyySBw75DtHT59uv/pybjVYoJB3wk32mPX6Rqel8Cw3U8f8hMZWrmQjDUaCPqkoiGDEfYrGWLGBw@PDo4rjBfar4IEIValdVW/mGVViI3Hn2/H/J1HIn7qzhGP8V5ZlC2hlbOQNFYXYl0DNQtcMEcFuMqqwlNv8MCZgU6fFsW0WkDNLkmTykz4eWfK0BArt9oCfQrPacjb20QBoX4h0dIFOqG2CkK97u/ZY6pQP94/gQQnh0zVMrJQ/4LNZMxQuhLqVs0y7MFkuImb38RmRoyUabORSeOfls3CXc0V0mq@2NrYsC4kzLNJ1XaBuxiv4PVCwmJ8FS4mfFVgXwUvuCAP3JrI/H2hB4dVf3MemjxL8B16opqHbpYUcB6bgxPG0asKrXt5IUiIbXzjGxNWr4N@LR08EmLALYYs2J8mmT15KFM196auQaEDxnrmZyZ@w1Dumd7Y0ufQdYAasaurqz5AOnjEtLpGrzxFD@9XXfLpgPtqpgsxu1KpvVVzRUE7rVTeZjVNAA9hS8ENcBvQAGgfwZbC/6oeZJLNlhTgVKoowiObzQo4dywIFUNgtFfkbaZWk3gbzOZU2ioi4Gcx9FlNCy8/7uyjRdxshsfFEAhgg4nLMkFYkYf5bwWB3oBouDuOPsJc9Ttn5t69LE5iZHOZcLaCSsyuoG42s7ksUlz4/y88gMVXc7bH9WxG3VbG4NTBmdtWdHB2wJnfVjrgNMFZ3lZMcE7rWTWzrUzrAhO2udFThjZVauLEmKGNZe4n1j3D6st4tqgmUgaauO0bEa8HCeu9Ws/p0hfUqz3ZxC/Z4wloniCXE6uOjeb4amiYg86Ms0TyQhjUzumctmDUBjJaeHFt3RJ6csfpzWVvMrfwlI7luLU4iIPxIGAB3QA5BOe@drLZXKXBWvLYGe8IWr6YaqgZGEDwp5bSWnrD2CkWKz25axm6u5Ov5EvpHh4A8pe4dvKZykD@4umTx5PJ@MigU0E7uTIkQJtoaL1op1TJ51uNhiimGpRNC7//zNmTtLEBfdrQexI8cQHMk7RSCxL3TLdWi8d3sqomqZVspnQlLAiHNMcS1gVMmsKSpZHuFz4HqNiODcymktbT5gVRodLv96@2LlKLF0G/kPgb0OdK0tOdi/C1KkXiVdg0LZmLQPDR@0DuC39tryJq@ZJYbVQX78WCWG1dCfdHRs/U8TBQM3NxM1UBmDKHGoOMmky4qriOM6l0jL7jGouIWbUQROQI3YyQE6/C7JoZzPHiZnaFSKTZxU0oubx4FaYK0BKuroDunNhAdt@ibZ02zTbUcq61DywIms92YOwWo8VevBBiW0efZet1qOqLXFHL5XN5LVso5IsajDflXCFfgs6WKWTymgZQcuVSuXgF7VpR3sboW3Zs7yJo7xWy5p/QK9wcZaPFkm8/Na2LUlbieCSS1aur2Fsh9tHRZxoMkGuvBAy6n2lSvZbNl8GVRZeWBYSZoGmSlpWyqqRm8f8Oh4b/7x9fg38N75AqqwknaKPmUxg2Yai32RO0dTFx2ImDXzsasAdGd02MvaFOO5r3XMfz/h5xHuj2KQ96aHLDsGHQYx0/@eaNzMlwTYzn4xGatzHcfzAI@6MOIIjskEd4ADfXcpxVEYrs@bM1pXwammIHYnBb7BD96ODjxyeR58n@7t5jocAeHH768Noj70fKsyf7j07C1yIPDZLmQxA/v//kyfVX/5E7fH7Unzou/oRHh89zi1vohQdmhRxcy5FCbwLi3/CVBEuQKEARyxcDhyrgMYt7oBzf8535wsKZQefn/DSw6YXb/vnB8IpwEhwR1hly2o7ButyKEWrrZGHQl@XVYlkQxsx2zlkxw3qOZen4/fr@BngOdTzuaKBAa1nYEjHrc8e1eudmz9gQnuLJyrKK3wpHJITHAGQ07ZJ1ChBm0F5tD78sj8tSHWtqsOmYrfWEB3qh0zUHQxiDz50ggtDRdQa/D70gvRG9Jrd7THge5HcjxLoZXQCdriSKe6L4WJ/o9aprVL1MpXLvnvrMFcviGIZk3RsY@zNotew59CLdnafFiSw@Yu0BrmtYzhg1EG/cAJG9rDVaOzmtXsrks6W//s0f/d2f/NqgpjYzexlpe@fpk3wFWBtIsYwEVV@YlUmt0cqlfKmc1UrpUrmUy6uFfD6tamnQCItlUAoyakktlPJlNV3KlUEKyZUhNF8u@qKwEsi@ylYFwNpd/Hb1NmlG8hBUIL4Myd4k9CSL6eH7lIkGpBEFVEIndHR8y6zBAMrUDMsWGUDUWZfFHj3ayzx6JIoP8AW3cexlRLGHL/lSJlN8IIoGheyVUKISHZ6mhFYAxQl/yWQeAI2nHAAa0BfFIb7sF3A6TRRNfNnbffQI8@nji4bpIdopD@EvVvBShGg2voCETgBeh9Ag2i7PJ0eI7uMLZokhj3jIHoSJ4scBOhhyxKNxAI@Dku7uiuIBf9ndxZA9KnaeI/o1fNmlSxRdeIGmL4oDcAxc6HSi2AEndgBR7IKrO9fBD78TjjbW7YkuinNOHiSQKM4ott49FcV24I/ZfOZjk0fqVuhF5aW@Ty9l/BNFLUAao2XDl6wo5sKXHJTt8ePP9OGkZwz4NXf5swslffw4q5uz6f6jzscfdwaDjjvf3f/4CIP29h6DNDKfup1Bx0/YacPlQKq9x5p@Oppfv6DUB@12RbdWBn2t3c7p9rWg9rxtIIaQ6jVg5l8DzGjU3oOgvcft@/qqZWQC2Ma@P4JnB68HI3g@0Ds8KLgoiJ6zTkesYvNXlGZCQH0BF4CxO54CL7XTI73rOlV8n9VYJo0iy7xRyLSqFMBGIPdnqlcY3k/gXce5n@TFvDGrZVq1Wa2o8X1I/YTYnGl5U0xvjHbUcr6yoe@oWi41q6D1CqcfZ3FJ3WEJ9d7WG5b4NLmjgQ4gNnd2JLGhtnY0tVQpFF9sTUUxWcH7TrZYeZPIxDOM4S3ZKLZ2ivlIimIxpStapVgESQxoMoEBvYNTMu1E4tzQT5NJxJYmCKAIVFY2p3Ka1X5ilp7VOF5snqzOamqV2xZmmRvAemjIftqdOC4HOQBws51MBVfgE6JaLomAgKIkksmQ6YG@Liy2gH7@9ZPTk5MvSOSr@3MXz1wDuVfVf/348Z58cBi8oQl6@RFKoo4r7yHXWgrhImngdQI6iPwYBlHQ5wI/PCXoOpa8TzvnQJwNAgKjSrJvDlY@ebwE53jonPOc0chClWwK2l2DoYV@s8f0Wh1ceo8lCCumJ89p@G7X67V2bUR2CKCIQaqvMTJfvwBz4HHcQ9MPlPwCT875Ae1a5qraqc1iM4DTrjFJfTlyei@1VLfaQ8P8D2oPMHG1Dc9O1agZruu4ImjTYrW/Y9emtqf3jWeGi0ZNDg43QZjA43SJPjOSm6y5j7H3UFO5kuousxeYfTodJXSp3kkue@G8XOiBxEl8PSj0BZ3wxD0aV9V@jSVeQNTX8O5uskRPfpDcyVWBTg9YOwlemZf9l32msUKuSppGAmFBVyL6YLl1lqzVvwYPDvu0UgFs/Io@BaiYGQA2exQAscfmVbVbs1hCYjOWJCLlqoNaA5Nf4m1bEsWWJDUuW0Jdkj4X6tBfq/OYXvOmHfqmC8t0VC1TqM7ATy3mqkOoXv3FrOrWxlMQECx49afz@GFWvQpEBdoBmDeXiXe/@M3ktpSvcb8qgbq0QPBoy@3arGqjlUhoGLVsDQJSjVwmDTo83IppGPO1QlotpLPpXFoqoi8M@Ol8GjxBxwEBI2ElRMbEdGaWkdW0aqjpROal2XuZTJ8mQGwhorFkeuLs29MRAx@oKmyb9ApPIE9K27JA9@o5TN@WqLECy6hiwYDqQzY200MEdWToFqVIJiWW3UpYmwmMs3kyHe83WpXK/mz8dQhKSK93CqliJvUmmawmNpI1z3gt1KtCHdkLlXq8AS3Xn@lk3nTUgFoGl1rUKo1GB4tYzKSzmSyUzmxfDrbFuthKZzYKKlTRFSO2wTjfiE7@ocSz8Bu3Ufa2DKg6taxVBZlm4rIlTSor@a18hs8G8pTC2GdvSEmWaIrBwe1EPF7U4vFkvIrrEBuiP/EMPI34WRy4a/yeuiOCMCZWxLKGERaskc7mZgLsQBy7ElAqZDlQbS@Eq4ur7brwFeEYT1xuay/wr/ji6e4h/n0FvMrwWnrx9Pnh88NHAlNoq6fcjlU3qnK1XYUXSa7fF2IVxoCTNn2rUsoGYx@6iTS1XX/Bn008PQBwBbL83GAt2txlmKi3sc/QYsEOi0MZdHfU0LRsq6EVYewDbhpE1TS1iqs0MTyfINehMrwLwG87VcfDfl9j87mekgJl/x5jg9SmQOSJXZ8J2K3tDo52g/1pu3ur5ws2ZwpOUTcFUcT9bLGLeCx@BX@xOD9aVcqLb4JTOwWxepopb98411MOz/XkIAZantwWYvfp5KLGTy6yWHh2ERdm/TWVbK7AkuVgyeMr8fuxeDyOawsV5r2NxW4iW8@cVsViIUuH86pvxJx/Tm/laaNSGzB/QRhTCwqOlX3tpQaNN2Y7gQdobzizBoNrPo9z@THl5dj7hlbKPj04tB@6jyJHnF7UY/jxbQlPa1UrL9obpyo02qyYPU3H2P0Y7fAXy4CVxj2qMXbKVMAixtpxtQKoCrHmxuWGg6s0LNw7@Nb@5OuMjePZXJyxZi02q@X8TelqvS6p2xoajSuyCoxFfbUgZS7rvLfVKaCgQci7X/xBbrZdgncto8K7puVTWr2ubmksGRu/@/L30f7Pxf5nu09YHOf2/@5Pfkcr/t2f/Cva/ha/ovl@LVuMQUx0qoVi7OJifHFxBRcPy8daMY5UrpgEN197UmN1RdWytm1XWUXR9a1iKqfdt6uKH1ctqsmYJ8X8HZ/ZQl5KJFQFsNrKljJJCLv0Y2qZErwFq148uliAGoEC7B@ZeU29v70D5dvJ5rTqBrQtNTwVy8K/bcMro/b59OUlY/DSrfcGA1Mjl6KwyluJbb@VttlbXHN6K22wl7U67l1Q8SxtsCazhWcLcV0yXk8pW3EGuhurN66qV60ULeqAjvvCMLbs5rXm2dzAwyXLXls2/BlbHv1hosDDg9fgzdh65YmJraSi9HrizWa/bbB8HRrMlrI48cu2gqUa/idJzeS7X/x1TSv83Z/86mX7sv2FBvpvuVxQtdhPf7o9taee0av/FADcYvsl0GFJjEUjLegIdV/GjVqafqrQIXdB7Z7aKOfz@IEmjLovAxnJHNhGjzRh4QzlOqrcNjc/2EtQtC00DZEmPYHMfSWrghAI1FwPcAfdNMFgW2iJtdFKChfCVzEIxAYGukRV@OoCFHiMQFBwum3PmrpjOpyToHRqK83uQRLI4ato2XGDTFr4Y44EzFfZupmUo@wR1UgGZCPD89BOJAyXwlchiW@u2pqzsY7WVzCmacMgJ2MUwpMCeg3IuwV5WzxBm3wTVHoeIc04djyRDbqC8FUQe4gKJkhDzNyGCFVgVF8FAkAZEj5gs8W2WTbJLsxUqrowQnmFxwjQTKYeWH4QMBlC66GlkSBxFeOBF@go@IFUbBd@DYMwGvEMgHAYfNdBDbQcTE5vKGCSaZb3BgWwyAxagorG7t1bYFWrmb0koxIh/FNzjHN0VA/2alwBWKAhftSriGmG5j2rgW/Y7IDiKUIXWp3E7XpWI0mZiK9XggD/791osUVeqyoKqGIB/PrivaILJIPESHZeh122XWOqVkyyEPku4N4lpOj8faj2NmcfydoXQeAVYPjTWPD5IWBaJ9F5T7/dXjf9wUApmOK3X9AAHGcGvskObuINmd/BJEgdpoKimBbF7psuKGS0HSKwLpnIqklMtrDGSXgQH9dyDPfb55P4oFQYm8FTRyuJfj4bZN2p60CFemPHJrOKZPYJDztAiwAe5Vuk42hP7XP8VphfN5Q4ipFH1uiw5SPGZCaSPrJOaXE/QscFxT2gTZoZA5l1Rz2mlVmCGhpZzrNDcElKRAh3QK5HGncsYwQoHRsGnZDzKooyAFlv2iHzgU9NaFfDRyaMQLan@N@zV87NU1M5QaO9ktPHg3TcGEsMxUPsfnzrg2@qz3KcU2aZpwafzk4smbLxGGg2IJyngbKLHxC2gntqtGwaJ1jUNI8FvyI8itxZSkfSbiTmyZvPrLqRaGONXtJ4Y7r4rfoz3Y7Ql65LwVfpvbkXGMMik07wLocs1/DN4NTiaOAitO8k@Ga9amRRSsZlknFCjImBOSx0CmPXOGOonAs4xgDT7AaGZbAXQ2m/SgMA9T3oWWglc@JW0BwSYOL2El3oej6Dt9lHLKsJGJHbKvPtigEMrPraMnQIg6RYDm/Sg4qRaW0A@Qr0zlEPwtAQh9/8MH3QutFNFkwXzZtt@OBw0KG8aox3i@AlH3nB3oHtmYq@AYEFwHAFJhsJMQVgU2JS5KDD9NeT89YuEC@psJuQ0gwh@KQGKCQq6Mhy0Axi5KNeAgQ80D3@5Qffhub5@blMhl2nrikbHn7oynNs3VLGAxNkbEeZGKOx/0lhEz8l78NduCT@fTt5PBzvzFC6rZXvzflTEPpezd@ZlIj3vTgOjmf4HafBiIzAofU1jxrUI5O@AddN@BulePvTWumLoP1VsP1JpfgVAmEMwczS83Q3DcDSne5pun/eq/oBZ9QhATjUohF4orllN3gZeYHLHPfDGM4E@WgY1LFOabEZIIl8JnqRNS9hEHMevPrvY3MGiWzjnO26rj5PUHgSY2MDTsxJ7GFzGPYpBJxoFfuC2/41Z415ayn5LEwOg1q41cJFC2/Cxe1AuSFoDJ/x8BmEz3j4bJFpkG1j1uIiGXpdYXGw1aNh0CAmgpkHca640eRFCEEGeRx0J/LDmPMlvyv4dWuUOqA3f4N6rAUNA9rEGAhuJJTGi2aj2bI943yrlVIG0NhFIgTUOIButIim573QjdS3zqyx4y152WgPFkYlH2/06g791sDbCpYxrCBqGJxeJprwHIz8PSFcIPALDBBQDoNAFA12JwkzWQ0Nj1MgNJyGuKAxR6zhI9Mi6csP8v1AXOKk54SNAmpFAKF/WCRAE0JY0HP4Zw0D7vC560CcIK5EX2IboSm5eCsOlLzWVTivqVIlRbCSpABNIDuKq7XrRQnCoSoa14Iixbzy6z@K/sYHo9@HfrEae2qwfMCoCtGugtswQYTwuwtRldVrkXoFDJQt3TJcGLn2uXzqj9aQzZYSqBk8HyyCd25OusNEpPK7SV4/dNhTtMVK2BTmtRoUcV7j3ZL3i4CknOBhMs9PNg8agp@eMxCAkVmZzPCTzaLJZrUaZxxstibZeQTJGSE540l47NkaJFt@MtCeDoLhBaunBdIp7hMVAZ7Kh1EQg8Yi8/QzA1fuX6GZS1z98PNc8BxqBX4bQhEb21m3tTL3RgTpCNO6BgAb4g0APf6F5IpwneGpUvgW8ihOyoBH8Te/GXBeAQ2MWHCVm4JOhI2MdGAQ@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmsHGvwz/ienAM/ipNz0zyzHVZc9M@trfP4hnCykb6aAR6UPN5JAhoybz3PZtqEZljhjbnYKCA1Jd59xhiRXCNvgrUz@p0rGcjjLScQcOfjeV@8rjeTLQH3ANiN0fOxN94uRyFa40mdTsVuXPdQZzYDv4uaWIOXiQ9XqO4dnxCVRq1xnYpmekGVrqPDV8tcPwv08hROVk3@l4guDvBeNqLILm7QpF3XYbv@Tebidwi2WyEu4Xpx2X2DzjcQH1X3BF0gN78oEejhNO55XRnSTvhonfNvCTnZjd08Th2A/EOdldBjysC/I/hA5BgmGes9AcyW46itKdSYK@yTF0Rs4ApL6pJwuY@hr4gwVsREgfjwmXNNNRpa1EvnBBvSTRTetJP@nXPjgp@5qW0JNhem0ZwBIx0sy9TmOkrLsiu/ba7HiyIL/jD8f3OIrv8e34khZ@HWeumtd44IdlnU0sIEDEBRrZu9HAogPf6t1AZwmV0BvlKp7gvVHs0Q63HmK6C1F3/ehyH9pHOnzz4C1E/LN19L@9AoPk@@9bfTp0e3Y8B34zws2iCfpCnhcs5SYg@kESec/N7MKm/fA984K4@HHSRyhCgBhLjMtGk8/QMcegdnvhBHIA@I42j5vKbrR72mlW44ErcHLP0uxUW19FD9s9w9LnRi/hx0xH4AYlPgKFjfjV@xUcGR0xPYfregkYu5JhKAzjSHQeqbKmyejps2RyfbPiUcyw9dBMOWF4sJ5@GH6DNeMUX43PVoMeEI/HcDr2zMTpz/F8POdfFbD459F8PsrHH16TaLDiboIAHfjoqaYX2SZvY59HibBI7zEihHHl5SKj0e8AItqBulmHH0aiu0sKlRtJVAtqWVj@ns7qGjdvq/FIqwjaJF@Mer8meVeje@82F2lqHNiChe192BByAzLuP@l2E1GI3OfWGnPsGzwB/Wiezl4zqrRXMNQwJXG6iUnqNskXSQE14wN44oTTZ/BEgANj0uYNKigbzmn5XxxlFDLSxxGpxfcBIR2gRKjISe6jEYklBG6IfnEV5tldm2f3Rp7dpTzDHrCc5f/b3deutZEsaf5GV5GWcKMypZKEDcbCwhYgbJ2DwcOH3V5MqwupBNUWklolPtS2@5mZH3sDO//nEvZW5h7m117F2XgjMquyJIFx99k988x5TptSVWZkZGRkZGRmfFiFMq1Uk3oUMDx3DUE36Ixukc74hL0z/blLbNP/en1/iNOKzwvhQiV01cLVQoUE8kKwUKnnSSgvtBcqW/wQLVQO@OHTQuWv9JDMrYUvCxUzLVBgSD/54SXeaxGO362Fymbe@ZoZ@Z@CyLTrLVTiMaUyL@QnU4RIgX6T1ogrtl5fd3M0DGhhY6XSVeCYyMX2ic9hXP6vRP@XDFmcOwcfccb5iAurRVVOLRrWiiHt0LJhcjPMmMkVvZrX97bZfisugmYWaY9n12HwpIbnFtLCSBDDV77RoL@EIORmZTZGylrJ7omObp04lAc53T5Tz2N9oJ3n78dU@CRphNOi6fpmvNIgZADvhycq34bnFDqmOcYId7LODLRA1J8X7ugUxjqNix59e4T4rDtdiLAtmCIySgzWkumkw/HlHBob9AdpJuGv8BMI7Tp8KCeTEtw7UY2lgp6Zt3zm17pnEAz25Hfu6o5VD6ilRBA@HpdOZJbF6wLLYnxKZJ2lqcrkIxQsmUMzPGh94pRzW/qRy4m4cXmtuG0ZMnWlSZZcaTFJlT0E4Lr0R9J6vHmtIyzX921fTc0bnLXkAcCqGbci8rX/Hfp7X/R3o1AbIkw0MEuxnr2UTqvXd66yE5h3k2anBxAfXbXlzFSO4hYSktPuwNLM7@K1KRUfJh@i5EujMfQJbd@QLd4TfINuk3sLgQUtYXiVfvlpiV5@WrqdUNMaSffKM0qLh5Y0HOl4jGnStbtxlY7PGmJ84fNtv/vdAzxMD7A9eIDHHRhOkFxm@fCyx1YuydwmsS1vIFLLFSWCnK9L42FOXpK456vb@NqWXuw197f2dnc@0KL79OlTR6/R4wQ/zFqctcbruEBmY/B4PZixbVlykRcKl904jo/O@8PRg4@97JQsEWFNyoBPrRj203Pc0bLMkucTc5fqSVmLohrWp2Qa@CmpBFXHx5IdarqOiCDBKP/I10CMekv0dnm35nAGpGaz518EzSYvXyZbsl7FMDTmRtz5W@5B8TIaclZgSd91nclwJAy1tafev64dqsPXdbV9tPlX9WHvSL2v7R4iCMLbo42dxqai/@q7B3WVSdlIItUhNpRE162gFSB/rVoqlZ4ohrzZH4xF7uQ3HXl/4F@o1/1WgGuq55F/8fJcfni9YLQuteq0HR3jDDPk1JYX4Qj2FpyLkbaxUG7a7NsI7wVFZU9pT3uBPe9Fvx12Qiqbwd53EAaRcYdT3ZBGkOSt8Qh3RUlC2kU2HeJ0qrDAuqbqPpXH3Q2B8cX@CiRGCcnT2PaUJlz8v@@m4GF9/82BQjyNzb3drcZhY2/3QG3v7dPPtx8au6@Ino2Dw/3GxhE@ccE3e1uN7cZmjV8IAiVPIdDFL5fR6E4UPBRnqrQ@4ebbG9Dwx7/Sp97Q4NW1z16ekVq47EH6hH43/C1oL6xlLiOoL/As5asClZ@v7b96R2u@Cn7FDae5Cmb7g@xRxKlA50vqObdGk2Wd5tuanq607BXKDt9HXIwVsgEFaxwAI8/PrjLA2YinHQYquwkbFZx9S5wMnssGNDX0gGADlDFYqSrO4rWw4D5nkOvUWqvbR1BTaU2MCPUPVH1pTE3WMkwxbSsDoPDPaPRwHlRei18Q39OLJd3saCgF1OP4hRRQT@QFVNEGbEfUsi5xOdq7hHhWK/Lil4vBNl8Lq6fxiw2fd7GrGicZNx5SX8VZEBE1pMu52uSUh/PJcip1rhJxeeQx63ZlYgSSQZNkolwlsm0blcySsOngqkGbvUlianwlboCdkN8ZRSpfdTx1COOgoBdKlryzrt8TE6jEdId5T60iQFNVO5GHcXY59ngZ9JkBkdkyjUdcb0trhcF961HNjakWfW0jyRlejQnatxDYmELgj4AhQIXUTqfFKxU73gJMv6NZOR/1iSNxbvu7XZ7YuX3ZClIVtNVW/pfwt98cTWQ3tU8ydoqMHQ3Rb8GQ1Eq@yuz0hzTHWaxyPi5IwdZ5fzAKZQzz6R7wjRMvc1QaCxu19nN1PdUa6DDZYq/fsxo9JS6@pdVTYsr7tMocL3fnsfhKEjUT59MiLHZ3QMc/7V8F1t2Zi0uk6wDHL6QI8105Dj/HI8ZE9M9MIjt@V8jvulpd39r4WPj9ZxdJXkUsSI5lY3SI/4gx0RZND77nY4PFIfQuPdNMcr7o8hS1tQ2elpaY5QYY7QPPQ9rXvWyuxd/E3Hj6PbyBJt/zyy9fqlKrAMmkE3NH5/lEurnq2DTpcp0TpU1ALNlJyJKsz5s3LsOM5fVLeABhFBBxqAc5gn37ROo7LUJM704vOyRZdAZiPdwxfEets0VFkr4dnj32eBR/ym9UF9edYmJQoixy5o2Idg3ksuNYZim8Xk2B27obHMnv@4NbvRM7WR6@C9rWndC@C7fC4u2wZFmyYN0f7O93gJXF7Q@Bpb67twOWRXIaWszpMXO687nYmvbuFn@eGjueewQGay9OUGKgVmuXPb6iNiHC81LBscEkCtHB4VZ9f19lZX9CdUnuYcvQ1mIQsB@ot4m1bdhjYefFSlO8WY6VJ/MmZdEW@1rdMZlnEu8WUaF1EFfTIxYWSSDyTngjUk@vLKxCsPU9C0RDuTR2n40Mio414K@0ByRkk0GzOpiZ2c2cLD5hZBuBa7q5ohvbNvxsYS1rN/L6Dsc2INsmyD@DZ8ns8Xsv@nHFtCMKFsI0ocNt0qRpvaF9wgE1PKCCnpcewTuGxQwpjOxFwc4Z2sHwq5TWsP88QzEjiRIuurAl1rVyrFET/XjeqDlskIhlwIelp/4oFs30wYh4fvPcHlAnWfTy6SWIlExken1pcwVVP/mqlzCmRrxOVmOF3J5r84zNscHyBKezGvba7YUewhZ6ZVI8TDZF0vbOpgp/n6ZklUi1ZGg@szPmI0FeWV5@/C3Yk70w1Qt/FrasIZPyc3QxoP19AjIaR3y8T5zb2HXN94QB7iCdmNabCTNRkVSdGWtKqu@8GNn4ES5yLkTIIK4@kudOtuqomwncZkOXFcmGzkWm@mBN4bijMmumqP/17uYgkL/Z3oPvb08mGwrBdPArrPLf9IdRkHjlWSFprFdw5U@/C4bDHhcTf6YLQMmzG9OdznbsbScGr9IrfOT7NrsnHe2dJGa3rjlr4Eb4eNFDvmyc7q1NHu8Vymt2V7cbO3X1iONsdlJnkdlh1rFkz4OwdxcCLIP5XALLB/vwPYwq9B/h4BqQRCb25sszbZxv4sYUIa35mBMvabNQLVvLk6PfiVp@D0FM3OzDSGXdH6gin8LW97adWSfrpbVUfUIuGvTyVMvNFrwsV6V3ONAFpDQIGU28txYseGoYS0m415z1YR@Fi63gRk7P2HLSL5ZXSyvPMty7njtyL46fnbiPWtWsosXX711El8Pr9qez/vlVR3XV4JfTm9b4t1@VWn6iHlNbSz9IsOPySrXI8WWf0r@r6lmJOVcj@IIDNyN/syeJbZVaUMk@fO2BcviBN80VeEhMcKl6dGG4EC52o@rF8cpJtVctrV0c907W4OQ3WqyOFsuLebz4gVZRkjFyM388OsGaap@6Br0rhZCinEBVu4Yodg2hN2/8Ydjfqe2@Sp3GQQHAEZi29eYDdcmVPQdrNvieeL3gOq@PyVwFjs1AQcrMsVdQGZ76fJ6M45h2SJjRqLikzUY3/O/YycyVvMvBqM9fTABJsJb6En7JzBk3phKfKFCR49CEmYR/AcFJyuRxMSRvx2JFXSiLulaG76RjgThGTRaH2Y/ZLHwKgaj25To@yURe4LfOgQSSw3/haur5c04VT6wWeXyKB1MOf8gOE6UTPOIChP4M@LYBTbDmHrHbR4a6j99lPMgbPqMasZ8MG8hnWFPEF5h/q8/s38T1nxMBhPBzonN5@ohTa16kSIrvIB8uIDpbeuOPawa4VcqgzKGzgC3tVRPgbCnONEKzmkz0fu4a5BRa0f90Dwpl/jXVjbi8I8WZJHxPrX9FoCUPKX9ax59uUi1vVSuYaqawRYq5b1IDJ120PXoT0LQaq82g2yWkhRZzCTnwyP69uv3FuP3oGG2exMjL98LU90LquyffBamklEcLfFKoYhfK5j4n5b6qbFLMnWqrqlh58WikWx6pJEnZtbvKRt6o3wyTwuvxUApXxh@epz4UrC8/zRh9@fIgVSdm8Pj7sXzX/L2kRz7GMlX2Zbp9/M3oAQrYeFbbmkxwqdcLuy8yOq@4/gI2yxI1lZLqnC9SmUlV1T6YWpyQBodzfp6269UEymLZSByeM9n15y@znlYyXuQn0RAvxqmJNWOOWFTiNheZcDfssEjt8OcHFgiGCUZTZuaum8pjXXlsgUWpB6ZZ8YKcmuDUtckpXoVf5Bf8YyZ7GjlTLjf745xgfiOdF@/mNIFY6D7IziZTWprAXURe6k7dsYokbY8nIc4WErvWKXDcZiA@2B0cgz@I5YQtKIykmKJ7/EVTOilQNux72xDi49fM34qPMq980rEH3eBG1bDN8NkLK5NycB8F0ShCGCuOsBNdDgZd3DqywnfNLtQ6fv/SMq5bEojWyu5lGrDskfIunrRDOlXy1B4gX8NAJPkQXZ6dwZkMHrD9a4hWnLiEIy9T643lQIPmzOMlcTMPFIJvsADuhmc2EjJyMntA6WjgtwIvQzpaRNpPRrraCXWWVT5Ph98IoqXRklbJZP7pMmx92nyF@9yn5dLjskWyK30dXPIeP0kcrIhI5sMSAh4ul59kMtbdcEvuhgsA6KodLPTviDeDq6DXCzI1WjG4YERKaxQMr4K2l8nsB/ElMOCClXEzCT/s/uWwJYc7pHT5xIzwEo5cuQ4jDsNfrM9yXdziuzI3g0ur5LaZhvoqbIOAxuOk08ftMF9YIEyA0AOVLoIREeWRo9Io8d2zxoV1lwscRBE1EOfEupuIydDrj8IWjQyfZGW6BEquQZLGeu0JTKi9VteHc7A3CwG4xyQUMAiYq6S7cMjoS/PvwkHpjpk7dt@MTJGkX5/nCk33YBiS9E0IzKPC1SzcaYAPXzcO1MHe9uH72n5d0fPb/b13ja36ltr4wHfcuCjn0MHq9d4OSZf4Nl1uzffoRbZ2QDWz/CFT2/2g6j@@3a8fHKi9fdV483anQdAI/H5t97BRP3BVY3dz52iLb98JgtrdO1Q7jTeNQyp2uOdyq6ZaJqmn9rbVm/r@5mv6Wdto7DQOP3CL243DXTSGW/2aelvbP2xsHu3U9tXbo/23ewd1hY5lthoHmzu1xpv6lkftU5uq/q6@e6gOXtd2diY6uvd@t76v2EjA6uVGnbCsbdAWFi1xP7ca@/XNQ3Qoedok4hGCO646eFvfbOCh/mOdulPb/@BqoAf1fzqiQvRRbdXe1F5R5zL5b1CFxmXzaL@OCEqgxMHRxsFh4/DosK5e7e1tMa0P6vvvGpv1gzWV2dk7YIIdHdRdhRyQ3DTBIGrRd3reODpoMN0au4e0Zhy9hb2DQ4P8nghDWNao6hYTGGYQ6C0RaW//A6CCDjwArnr/uk7v90FTplYNVIBFxeahXYwaJCIe2t1Uu/VXO41X9d3NOj7vAcz7xkHdoQFrHKBAAwYZH4h1qNEj7jXGifCSR2LWjOFcl4dTNbZVbetdA5jr0sQBBw3NLUy2zdea5h5CC1uHKGEfZwb@hX2w0pl@dRUgmOb0iczsM5o4YtLm3ladVmQd7CqbfDiiVWd1IpSS/Y1Wmvgj/UyFrGkHp5dnzbDX6cPHNK4mBx8X0ZmLzEYO0sJ8zNyR4Eufr3CFXK7ZfFdr0kb3oNl03PvUTKHxrRr6GPyuUo7uI9JGYOeNg59KRej@PEWo9R/0RScb6uECAiWF@j@I6Zt/ETiqWGwHuhqc9wHYHB1Fcm1yjqsUEo3s7Ih8NkmTfDLBv0PNDlwxb8B7rSbOSWEZyYX6Ef3T@5L8kMXBekHSWY67ikVsYhmN8LfANCONcEgE/kdHJAg73KQXBcGns3zJbg57fu@s32/nHcfU4bIj2gee5Z1vVD8NziaqFybrM7J87awzLkRm380qTHz/rEmm9Lh4Q@5ZHv80R/zHMdhIzAecmnJTfFitDy3zP0h1WCS5Soe2gHsFDzJ0vje1HxvvsZsrLT1Zm3j/On4vcwv2ggi7SwveMdc74T@vT6QATTCOxUEkCXWEjGLRqmPsTeLC11TwHIWuwzYsf2itPg94XSeSkCJ76XftNrEaD8MbG3uSw6/2a282jra3SXQC2yery09X1jJx2K0fXfn7Ae1wZFyOOjagdZz0NP5kzZJNUnx4pliByRP2ZwYuFlEQIefNoPFLxHmI7TbSlkwQZOhuhOROPZjoZQPQIas4AMeDjOHXmTNTM0A@1VUHvbnwb1jF90lXYh7QxizdMY/aDf4B7Hj6myked0gzkGYxjhVMnEu7C5Z72W1jKsqbGw7cgyJe1vCxhHGLacBHXWw/C@9a/qV52xrFSEwZMV952LkmIfFgEgtl7Cp6MrPfcpwRfQDM0cPozY@a3@jxgw5wx@Hu/GhUGx0QGbfjmjinTg6jdaePNeQTpABBUDXT0nOFU35HI8VzTx8nx4FBrNnAqCCfDWx804DX4jgik02yBezLBUd9Fk5F8A7AWdMcq38T587qjoayZuKH6N8mKoUSWHGQE6HaddxGxhT5EMexMORMkelP0YPh/wNpMgP@c9pxEvSEWlYQwHtRkqEKrWj7ykQJr81Fg3W7kVDTfvUhAfPVHpjzuGP69uZG/GuIBHp0xubFBw572MnPIACYHAcb9vyNTdLOfdo6vcw6ujruSXqti0Fe6bXCLBVTcAsrJy6rXa65W8EPRzly1mQ1uENV1UvZuJ3yrKct08RWXj2MsgLOMfE/io/4ACSe8Myl52K1OslZJT3LjBzQoZasBacdR0witfTrrbd2j5QVIjMl@/XNlyEUgV4HPtP95FwofSXmuemIi7wSq0OOgof459gmY/HRIetO2RCzGwDOwzYfhiBdyugaC0RXoHOovgSayj9kQxE0klgdJnEGIW4dj0jLy@p1jD2fTIJDY@yPehJ6P5BTLVPCkwAfGkPbXd5Tb/wxody9X7eFxYqPDvoubBfRmBxL6PpIDdPq94ekOvroN@HohmPHU@/1oUPQiy6HOn4hrWfhUJ9IGKWfmoHaJLt3XmYk5j2jFoUjeCu0PeYP7tJFAAtRCU9yU1hReWJew6Pr5tAxvFksq/zz5MtzogmHJWUiPlcr6ssXKSUE1SFDA6ZgGMWbC7bZ5HZw7xBPv@v@8BPWfqhAvXbQjiOTWiD5LFAGqdHjGI@tkXR90I/4RIOGAicgMSXKcpAWG6rSGv1Us5O2a8om0TERu5R78v3txExqrKWooYRxdevEfCsFGkxQaUmHBo2DhZaXlhmVWRuur7duxjhaaPraWmU/9mKRUhElovrQqI54ErkZP33Akz7krz6MMHvoDe64tQoKhKGz4l51Ws4xfrApeB8Gw7Z9JkqaTNsf4PiNtz79HvOiOTrUYf9a/igKxrQDaBXDmyLDaOb/0j/vNTf7Xf8s7Ic@7dMQsP5GJB4ex/yIATsb9q8jznrEH9pWofY4eZb4MhKGDb/je8k1KzRXNAoGedtMYTQc184lTASfnMMIMMm4yvw9mIyRFtd5spxUyqT9T9ker@ys3Vr3cXlWZbnRBwAt4NYnLCjEh3TEjkmW8@naVIHTuwpYOJ6qgvKdWyz2Uhg/IxLxNUwKY4PMlFmC3QnszG7F@Lh947Y5BuEQgZaCrQAZfKI8v3Z9JLEmKfIClgIVVV4tWVXlFuUGcQjxML6d3EtP/8HYEwJ/Av3y41ncMosRWMR1TLSlSPYrOsoo4cLmgSHLaJbEJMXCs7BnuR9yuoybSajpz@PbqMGWP6QU6TB7U1yJGZmnjQ@S8@WbJHKaYweLyoJacDhuB1SQ2ihfup1hg2/Zz/LkxyWunJxBMG1qyHkL6dtI1SIqIU3whHmtjbLEVP72jFlauu@oTRCwOsvkzEpXnc8azYU9UEJZX3Gt1R@SMM5OUE@beixEo/5g4Z7Uu1V2zIzMNovWLcf5piGwMFuVFstHbSZtdYzH8VpmEp8JpklTjC3NiIewfeXnmM0niXhTbWK@VZvjb9DhNpoldlPxohKPd1vmPhbFK1j0moUmnlKMO4KUrsXvj5vU8ebtEkTDlO1VkyVGEyKjOZZHC9QEmWIq3Z9CzH0a9wl6tIlyaLdNtLPH51aiThrJmZCn5lMqyCXoicDtcNokuTTowPgCYeJEw42FVKxw3rhjvsorF04RZBgfBCC04qCQnEPJCW4yWBN8xNkBOvkmrIXKkET0tG5bOMRB/2OCcVR@fbijLR6a40L5ZE0g3cSQaFfBpe6CZPzN6edx84ahTJGCpvgMUsQ9mpJN5/fv1Z/tC5UjCFKbP2tL35KLzjhqkbChf@xPzRvowElTumZqRqUnQpNFA80F2qWcdQPZrkL7C4fC8bBu0NOINhDyOo8/i7oGwnmvlGJqo8pNe4wijia3zDZHFdalSsJQ8hvk11NRVF3euBKAQDCm@tUyQUBYU8YelwIcesfmvBSieoyoYrWMaUkvOSpqYuc54zuIqgs8WbZKlGaVeGbDKMwEQorF7DIJIqSzzC6SQKGFbiYuVomns/uTlCCF2PC@UJyGQo9KmobxyAkBOT92yUkkynFZuSXNwfzxybKT@hjzN399VrK@lia/En1iDI8L5cmvq6XU11SzS0vpqqmaRA/HbjX1kUjh2AjHUuHP/Y9dU@yQ57FNqLXJSGkZ2j4b@ctpl0n7Nu@XSD1np2yjYxh4tme42X41JcVKKij73QHY1QJfGSB2@5/urbFMNZjoXAEcl844u@RlQ8gaaxZLPbqFna6JtBcHKDB72n5HvTvc3k6FfT0dG0Oji2C4XCqVwMSndvB7Y1uNo6SwX0yXLnYuu93i4Povw3enRZb9QcApASpmBx3QkNCkiLz@8EwyQwAHKorSBe3Iir3@Zadjp2DADSUGj4ZNSupoCIoXoDA2enl3yAdADFIvsD@jg@jfzyqefde@KJoairmGotowCb7KmtszIg9edGCfHd9UMTAIZmPNROuWU13/jBUEmU14sDh8sfM5MU/Ovg663b6r3iNvMiIFzH2drLC9bVcoSRHcMLJ372XE8WhdFVyFXcuvGEVsXgc4szCZPBMmLjxi4@8HZ/WbQT57/FOWlhXq8iK6uYj41K7KnmUdHSz@HmCFDwnte5W@8Af5FtNpsjAt9XoGJ0@E0eOyO3Pvkyri8JmYptm3S4Oos9H1OFgDdd1hXcDEsufh5Z7cUjwmbvbjTbkDGpYEhsYJMVfuVwOuZv84sXg16nTuJxU5DYAM7HdJRMmE8ucEIt8B8AzU04/oiSjafy3QtN6eCCgiCg6SdUzLHVRookIm87BV/fU6X6vV1PxgcVHVahv0UCio2kZNbeHFxobaot8b@P1DdWl5eU1k7pbzmV5umJdf1QbB4BPOxdb5cIt@0rcq/MZgrY0hni9W5921@Wb1@fpaVDyubcCtn57@81/@53/@6/8q1vSPf8ePDf5x/FNcyPO84nzr8/wPX9fw@3jrZGH@9Hh@cLJwtgYu@xtHDe83RgU/MR/1hqeZnKwC1lu2IzX7bI4@o6sqkyXwwh9@IulSUblWVMzpt5FkjmIZm2sF1vsAfpSntIU3SQcmt/KERI6AjnEcT6PTCmCAR@sNUZJwgR2o1Je7FXNwj3AwcYH4ViWnI/GwznoVwKcliaQAX1xasQphLwp6OAG/Yp1XupfJ@PQ3HDU1/xZ/ehOdbfRv1KOPefWopB656lE2y3/KK8/orTNfDOGdK8VoO5DNuvQluVqAmaGKQlb0eP/AuXYmyJ3JzHPKHkAyYSq4sHjBufHuj51lJOFadJaZQ9JQJUckfMmEKrnP872vNCyfqcTXbMrVhhWFpt7FcGPWjUo8vlCB/EgMAZKWL4QglT41iZs@9kjGU9G80WOd4WxCDBhk3X@1zfMeL2gtmu9pm@fUXgppjth8Xt5ibVwTZ2hGG1@k/QQBvlCR7WSJPQkXcgsZsfK2esndFC9su3@a@cTWYRyMjG26VPpdWUwg1tw24eZ72q9FG3LL9YrKhvH1itVUdtL2W2WsKheX3VE40O4K3Dom1Oe4ta8ykzCiDEjgSMz@yvQM44MCEylqYlgkWdZYtfvousyEnnZNpwF2PLk5sohQ/ClPc/vLxNx2iuwlYthBeICRik35On7YjXTUlSET@8wfniI7oN/hhGojuTfj8zwkf53AuN@JkfYYMpucJ/OZupIbDP2zC99Vud3@4dAfN2jZIs1n1PIc6iFCMAEJTD7d9KzuGYSlR3pImCJxV9hyCMkLumOdHk3GNhv7nGBIzVTQYVcwCVLsxJQMvqTGaoKOCVd/xyDYKE8J7/g2UotYlrywNNKQsrbbDE@zqamTMS3YcyeeONmMoBrPTMMLutIlFtoLvvglSd5FjADddlZ7AWpXhJVnaB@r01nQ81OL06CbMY7@xTUl6yLmM6eiFGukjIbytJxkvANWpEf@lI4CIWuTCWeUmcvn5z5GOp1bzl5HOMh3bItf9FUYJ6DjBGbsGaKOeqEIy4kVKsmB4akGW/4ThE7XPyP8xtf@GKz4MZd/8aDoHP/0sXfyKP@x9@Xjbw5jokWyWWULKqcvs43E0nOFVsaim/pprNIiE2rwYy9d4GNPiQ@LRQJCpJg//ql48qVICH3MOc6j4secECQ1ZMCkeHd7RYAvTqGZS2NRzGXmnEeOGfz8i7KjaG3lvxhDeeHIX8LCbCr5mJ72OcMOgWI/3V8vxeUkKq4ulZ4slZ/QTugsuCkMg0ust4Xo8jS4IVUiwnaWlp6Pv6W4IUWIrzeRv0Yvb6ifktZEfE8i7aSkRaie5txOJmYrquMJT1B5ojKHS4WLixOX8XH5iA2/q4jlTFmOBSWmgxb35bF@Rv0LtONHkGuT3iHCkbAyEBsRPkItALJJvnIbhzpmuiywn5OnNhG7lYHQ8BZz1mrR6/cKWllzvIU1KNHwmumullZLk3N0aoqmZui8VqYWHqjy@oun//Fve7/mRrn1peL7If0d5X7Nrazm5JEe6Ndj8@sqt557jmIrX3PjIu2B6fHpf/xvqr/@F4KDL@Pn9M/6soG1Ms6tF6pc5UtufYUeyktL1O7/@ed/pj7My44NuVjnm65ixNYMRTb9HvMufVcN9FK2pQuJWGHHLMAQC0Pam9MPGEbdLK2W@Jgup60qrgId@crYo@glng2zRmwqJCcZxp6CNCOpUEUDBQFpTCg6yrLdMGYbYN4ETfXzQ28loh3Az9qcI24yNt14GMFkaF62RTSAeWmR9vPysF56kY3NOypZY1OyZlRIbO20rF19vEbs8LYfjMJW2krCTNeLln8dnHrgQy9oX9Keqhd1@78Mi1fEkhflpdViB4f7RbbjLg4YUmEw9n4jRVAnA6KNIRudumpII9C/QAgvl7MFkUK/Hd9JmXySpGUPgpacYaVzElMR8fFz5XoY3fESVTrP/5ICj8yZOhGklSvtY49q7u1XVHYxLijleM/rAJu3bByrQ2AUxBp2wLLJy3AfcDpo@uPVhmfshMS1EHVdinh@u9309bd8Zi5rUqW5mbnzoDuoZjsS3h2xU3FjoukvauatUAohThAKBRZ0gHURjHzaolez/Ab78aQFhEnRd61xqLiErB1dVu/q21XOunJH09fS9DWNKLSEpJ2YZ6xobMouJrKliqPKYdDEldrMhqm1yCRtHnr8BxhEMiyNDtwSdHfYA5KolnRHW5XZw@byXph45DoQnz05WpTM1Zlc4vzomhLiQQ3dCe160hgJCETBrcBCmX4fiAdE1aQZDXsZiec38dnE99BguA97CCVqh62T4KOyLPWukPsmHLEvpSIS6Liytg12RlaPGHQcYitOQZvFwUvWAUt1KrzZ4oJmOCqcBtqEhMpm5ZzquKXi9LIdnb1WEkXQi2ypvPT4yfLK09VnyHI2p3s7GwwqedgFDM59gsEadZ422XhfrWYXsvIKKainmwT0WWBxAQezrmvHMWGfr50H1XJJAytlGdY1p9GQ6vq4kkEmEIeBhxWB9ij5YTaff1E5RsdOPradL/Qf8beJD8gMZ8LR@kJ6axzeJpGpMhcScKDKgpmD4uQfI4KKo7/YZYN@Zx/RJgLYugrbU0M7iAAxOh/2L8/Obe7wdGirQ5owRHCOS40d1KtglAQYs7CCLqoPHBqW90XVwDue7gGMcrEkQOcT4DTNdNxKX1uaYnYs0CKEyJrwWMUVomU6arMzc2evr@q7W5OI5ew0dAzXsy1bSbnjSGYIIINcvVZ3D4m6OtoFu5JqmeSmoiqzgCuhXJnd4X34SreQiNqiipHVrDeM8neRpcy8mIQ2TarSOAKvGTDLpW@T0vi1ml6AIEYQ6tOkWIi58X2OTbIEJ3uQMU/By9mKZSP6JowiDjCnG8s62qKUC3FWgbnMLQBxblPKSkdKFYwoP9Y58bKMNpI5ilc0jga0GXK8Uw1mluQ0E2x1G0kAbGQdN7RA/xu7m67aqtM/2@@3XCjKG7W/ot9xiufb8S1rfMsV1dg2Q2BHi2WbW9hM/QoXJWKWkg4YmyAI4duRrIhBEjWg3tjWtJdJfZya2ycJV4Bdfa2Em9NRPUkQ6IXPQOb05j0OxcHuOvyuIodX05ImDqmip4Uccd09sS2azCWtxpCElPcAsTQJIg7UknD7XMLwYoHOmrev9y6GsRvbs3k6xbKyoSK1fbtIZE/z7K2UuYstljRbLFUwjnfxBfPtnbxxGnT62hctZo5v8MaDP8YbhfszR@G/BXPU/zHc8Vhzx@MKZI9wRxw2nD06OQ17fwbHnI55DW62w7MQ50Md6yc6UXItACzwgCF8SOljuYS@3SJOVH72h8XJ9QhGQkvLcAz4Q51/ojv/pAKZy49bwX/Vzhf@zp1f1p1frmCtmTHyWrWzwq3/fXqcqIT59IuZwwt1V4o5f7SnK7qnKxWspjOG@f97Twv/j3r6VPf0aQURE@TCQcLX383NoonUDjYbjcTcwsvooF155LGfzZUO9l7tapY2D53uZXRehbau/jD@qxr/VUgjfkIaOtxFxLah8V5etqfiLC@aJZ9yKDhZSU@kvyYyutVfvWAl@xG9QImQ5oOtod6okELuysfktslL9MdE@saLz31xFtmuk2Xi4tzaQMuOsOwkU1w0X50kc2klXle2OAay2jzc31n8H0KGC/@T9kIj5DG010G3a1YSewt2GEed0p2xugPYB3rPkWIVTU5GdqS9vWN2mbtdqnFgi4l1cfYmQa7acP9He6kL6BtWVm4cGRFtPF3f7Kpgmmu2F/KG@i6FZndZ9/gPcekzzaXPKmpfbwxuI5WvD/w0Lyb7tKXl5bvWAKnl4Q8mYMml8nfMqv8L)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/36bh1)

Use `git clone --recursive`.

Command line: `funge -std=be98 polyglot`. Standard must be specified, otherwise it autodetects the file as Trefunge-98.

Funge++ is separated from CCBI by `k` with negative argument, as described in [rfunge wiki](https://github.com/tjol/rfunge/wiki/Undefined-behaviour-and-known-bugs):
`01-k` acts like `0k` in CCBI, but does nothing in Funge++. `0k` skips over single `;` in CCBI.

```
@,,,"369";@,,,"364";k-10<
```

Answer (score 1):

## 373. Befunge-98 ([Language::Befunge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Language::Befunge)), 16318 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata>;re;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."4F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $p/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@   @,,,"364"<\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<      @,,,"369";@,,,"372_"^ s;k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@  @,,,"368_"z;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6IDW2jNm17FWVfW4abu96Co19dvLo0XXfLPua5Njs0U2U1BzbnU6cg8l1@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBxaAmBPDKmVKmetBRahPY2J2l/KBgEemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2bkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGvNzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7Qk0DqYzD9CwjABaUohB/IdGZzpgznQynk4Y4NYzPb1jAdDOnPWMvj61JmnWgTAgMvmfDw3bb8wATgYQJw7H6tWUUDMWbV7v9VgG2jHgcWowE6hGaFVYNgv@zHGBahArwMgHRu2al9GYQZ1BFfWdCstnMhC@H/ogtrrlOT4yy6hhoA19leoM4T5znYGrj4AaPYNo@tnBM@Z1HRfe4IdxeX@6DUxXn7DtbRbf//RhnNXDapHdjhBWUY1dQBXEgkB2pltTaCHRmnCgftwwtYBVFt@IV1gcyKJlWC7HctBtS0zLA5HUTBkc0P@1rAq/AtNKLKdCD8rH05hP39UHpmVwKAOEUsSGr@WZBvdMjmXVEo85cKw@j9alzIosW2KFIivmWRHuZVbWIDcEnWNqOQ@/AvwAWhlQUeGXzXFAi3YP7RTb2h7r6yPTmvvQCXyX5VVWBIiArwqQtRJAgGc2i78s/Ait5SsKezIEag/1MwAvWeYpciMjZEhYhQo8lK0thTgislyevTfE7IF0QLR8iRUh@wJQIgcoAGW1EmSfz/CCeEPDsvxkQw@TEbbFDPwA8yLQoQTUzwAtM0jMIvzgHfidBoxNAy6mAWPSgJloGrizmAXEK0BYAaqy4NNrqHunkBHPR@sR8YGjAxgVqY1MTEUiAQSoLZaFOiuwHDSELDaEfJYB/oBLscCAj5VUVsqxUpEBPcsZBnWjAl7YSlTgnyrgoyIwqH8VGoAKOKlAbRWAqtk8EyLEVrMYDmmzkBZIo@YgTQ7cUHFqAX@QDlqGClmqkKemlReNEHDT8lDefJZap1aA2i1CGNBNA1w1aE4aYKuVIBzTloCGJWy8xXiaE0JHOkCtYHOHdgjEyAM@BBfiglsrZjn9dGs81DvIrXnKTh@TFrAbFJCMkDSDxYNnDqkJqGQADPYCQF@DFpAFcmSharO5MHtLBSANBG/0TGLQlgm8Sw0pVExTg3yljycLsqkFwmg8nwxDP437OcA4TWB@xkDvzsNA6H3pMHDhW8iir0a8dgEok0NfDzirM/WsBZDQkdMoK@PMtBZ@JfLrGXqvb3rDtwtcc5RJx9Antnm6yCWfT0eIqkcCChiw5FXMRuNOTAmGq8EQXYuyaEWMM3bCClpCWVUJvY7Rn9oDQyqXIvhRyGTqTmBgWeRZ5t6uORjAmLyAo6apmDRQLrzzhKGVzU6E0BOpi3m6Jgzf91h3CAJFGFjm8MvlBYyshjDmegdHdQmkMBgFyjhu9c0Z69zr0qixQDBLdOoOzXEQubI2cqRyKZNZqRBpG0S5N6VMyJrxasmvHNNOxFk8KVwJMNZwyTI6UsOA9jmOUjjuYtOFcdUhqWHBPhN2MDImgWjLgzyMuhawUaiUro4jMI5HBo2nARxzIjPIBMRAwzlDsZUGxaVsPBo4Oy5KqSDl9AzXZRgXRFsvTUOsN@14xuspylELvPowZhswtPd10woRoHFEn5AAAM@4B/nNl9Huu86IBpsRDqGW44zXiCswYJ8joMfOubFAfTGe6@OxBVIT@BtcaANkznWSt0k4j@bKEYJEmA4qHABSViBtmK7RJdr7RYfUWZBLllGsMK1@L4tQHkTEqSx0FhA1PExjTy2rAnKO0WXZutIzzhT04SLXsqiFOARCGIhSPoiODrIyYk5YhJDuaTKJdydBzXrOaLlofHw9CIs@NFEwss71OdReH4ZWY6aPQKJnKDZDz2UjaDG8BrEmQGfBYh2wnmPHJyGUcxeEWCh0WBISlJEmE3NkgPbjQBKs8RwhjaM7YdaZQ1MmauVkUnc4JtcIJQvXCcU9chEP3llA3OtNu0g1zNu0qQWBmOShjO8Cq@R@wsRlzaYOPxfkubGv4cnowIjHiFpEQfB4b/cl7y5BRBnVsD1QKzyZmah/QcsfOH1obOcmlB0YFiRdwO4SEZAEoddM7soCkRwb0OjUYibrjscM/GFQgub5KFMCEdR5ZbI3EGgNQYXoTl13zmZjqAlzBLEmXaffh9b7xhgPAQQb9Vh33oXuCZWMrUfoOcRguuPlYi7eNg2IY6NSsvfs59nAALKDwNpH7RSb/KIA4zEVgUih21yYtXWgFBahO54TWYTYIkXfcWT07zmGR43FcU/Dro@ZecaAugb0s/6CGY1QOIdWapNS0QPO43cvhI8ZCisLg1n5reBjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdJf1QcmOiLCoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXZm2hF5//ARyvvkK/nAZG8obN5n29daDUQNW05ElkX9B1Ef@2qIjrzW1@QlEjxClZNzFmt@I3uIcXYtd/ElxlnC4KW4BocxdQlUfohJTCfISpA7mt0h8sIJchuSt6G3udObxQe/aPbuiEn9MG/ERgW2I8hK6IV4rIchwc@6CUgeWwirvuSBUZc87gCte6MVkJ0QSasX9ZUVXQameBfQkWM7K6ACMUO4GGU5hOqCGuMxcg3dChsjdRdvqY6QYS8ml3AggzF0PHZc6Bmc6cxpJoGqLNK6fAU8EY4VSZk9WB5aYciI44A/wVEQEowtHdoCdjHsqaBZ6cApgIlxBRl4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidE@vnjQnGUts2UDnT3TkHAsWD4RkymjPTdYENnuEgwcegYDCRqZ3CmKD3eshZkRzU769nLmOL3pt2zNl1LbyLnvIrTzjTXdZHBdwFoQM6USLe9@LJKvlTykiQqDjjiUJJ@V2EiBRJhipP9EGnh0HiETCa47ndTYhLXUxMM3E66ZfEJDgwIZfR2CegKlzHDtUHbDSjU@jX9FZlAxi@JQnuEvoRJhigyBiguyBnQCcELbNc7nV0dgncw2XSbI@rIoFKosq5MC/D7oV5@YRAXKLllXkWntslhxQZ1bAEGJ1KToPEEgHfkxKUUAQPRfHHVvQgaY@HkVzDPac2zcOxBBdFkuwiFH5hAEgQMiYIH2bXnLR9ceXevUBw2ajVoLGBNAVss5eMarTBhKUMnBoiyySN@JnIE@d4gn0jkYTyYuQrjg2ITdBSa3V2MRm60OPo/UqASEBWwcaWHBDWr@dPzdNp73pF2@iJkUTsdSA0md2JWBVg8Oe9oXYbVeNLVAWtN45UxcaL6Qn0jcZLvlihoh/NNTwUf2s@KpEaTiAGfltdSSKe1PdbNOi9edfyRQLugs7OuVEH0D/1J7JCRpT2ZYKg097oqRwIdgcOhz3bPXlc8/siD1Q6pl1Z8rCcrm6R9yZGF4O0Tw4eHO0e/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@GH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8/Doa9dJApIQkoNyADf@rok0PA4IXUJH94bXBmE2SKUgyzBJEJdJByyAGToQdQzXA3yeTd@8wcq7jtTY90fMrKnOAQSeyoEdpJMx8JoAFgR1@nxEpLQghZo2LjQsXNGYAT4fo9R8HRkSpSNN5uPDR/tHNQLrz6tJFEXxJiBL6W5PhjZvTUEFXxUH2B@4uiwlLxBHeZpwXUngbneJwIu6ZWvgAwDUdWSHSdYoKJo3BNz3rpeNfKVu2ALonSBclyuj8lD3QxGN4IFDXBdV3lWjKAUsBqvQa@WIFYYuD1vdfN4o5srRYau7yLMXBUqLAjAOBHKjC0GnnoQ@8kKK9MVqH/3jJzcQ90iIBFVACjDzLCZTXp4loPYimSzuKXugoTmWIX9OHE9kYlJR4sG6gNz1SPmMxN@fmZNEJsmfahLiQu67uwfawyCyP2VNMxmkNKAujiOT28f1va4HbcR2LGfgsC1Iw6XDIEMQm9YWc3fg2DdqSEdPLGoMlwiB/@LEjT6GscZ8Q4ojpYqqq3yxUbe9c@DSaiGLRCIKESiF4suv9DMdyLUo9/HBN/ZhEFHzmUzoztAFJIikIXKhqxvxJQ8mQUayj8/KAobLhTd6exAgRdbrsNA@owsT7i6CV3oSx5SVlfFXovSJc4Pir5z5taYFPrxpgSNCsoNPnz05@HT/6e4XzYmWzy@95zLlAhAO8uuALCQPOd2wt27xronFQnAx6Bsudi/gAlNQUILVoqnnAuOWMYrMEVjTavhCa@ITZ2jHveT1wpxjqPTK7vIm9BQ7H4/qJwRFu2ehMuLy1Wocz7H9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedV1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQpAxpsbPAWf3ALRYU4ziLo1ckB5oTVvZA0swcHTrJVlDoagC@PCuOEm5bAFU2mUHmgIoCsrYdmIAdMb0NZ/BvUk8qb9VVUr8XatZrScIgbRlro/xN3oG6A6JWC0AlIkr72y5r3mPTYHLo2QrgOJMXmLJjk8hmOBxUCQpFlT1PMD4hC3wPlS5BVEo9dTnM0FLqXkM7miWsgroJaBmgYyq4RzbtJIn3SH0sSRAJ7k9GneINIK@15Xt/vylu8IkAW57yMoarbxotm0WyCgN@8Rbrju3Ji3GmorWWU3k2z58ZNVaL1LxcO2G3hA2yUnNE16sjX8rKffZGc9nXpXjymT0dgfc6Qxe7oLgtQbB/h1z4j2PUygRAOVraW4CkZ@q6yYELIwqYA3pJQCHQpGWmh6CuIlgdCL4iG0HOBbkQRsMZvBy8H3d0T4CCrd2O5NJ@7RGgnKNThb6o2BiDTZ3EUu7eH84ARGx7DlI5eGykUmzc6NOM6j6x6frYRE/hp/kB50tRACzcqHM9J2uKsBGgGlIvUcOAe0K5w2HS5mGVHph5YGGRJOOPkAEoRNqwcD4DOQmBdklxeE50Q@y0U6tZ1zG6F1DFaSOuaET/Y7UxfXus1etGwQPavxOACNChfh67Qo3jG6fJaVJ6ZSgBKos5ExcnAqAaQrYgUGFUHnC@qoC3o4Yw3dKiPhiiHAl9j9PeBiXYPPF0kjVKKgSe2z@MRVdqVvKLr0BlrzLbIVFj5SxX6lnwQEWN7eQLMk/gwoSSfOiCJ9TvMtGPggEHcFXDGEEkMLE/WaMzbs6zof1wgTySptQ4jH@SLQRXxjYyNeidfjaXDtgGsbXTvoSoFrh1wSuTCejC5KkSYXhjYoBfq14leNAPIs2cI2MEPJ4Y05TuiNSiXbSusN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6Ewmxfo5rtmA/B4p@x62neOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9nSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt50eylmlfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXL0qQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRI3MGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/YYxHs7daIRw1g2kbJxBX@xVwS09yMWjXPINTx8V6JY0/UDu5fFAuMXJO5SXxnPO3QWOaVNZ2hkVjLtnUn/kTHTlMxmUJjkyXMY34ookwUhIIRwSFfup6WEX1m3DmXrRmcaVE6CYO/ieDKfALIPtaWloVeZYMLpDh8U37wN0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16QOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8ZDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSQ5MnqCBfyjD@xR5nXhGj1lS6BVWscdwggBpUFOrIW1NfIDFMcb9@TJDJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh85z1NE0rdPP9ShCGrQKIPYRKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzPp4UCHf3Tw4f7fO6EBlscXnEerT1yelOQK3296ciwB2m2D@3JtJ2RCWQI0r85tY4cZ8K1fHhZNzPDlWZzNLV0mvO5Pi1za7qu03Esmgq6Leki/tT1dEvnk1BB6O5nT0HWf35yXJMrkUiKfja6NW@ch1ydLafnQXTNkdZbg@UhjzdMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDoK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjgusL1QNfI/m/T7S95Z8j6VkDVZC@8cefO9oEs6YhSlPI@EG0OX4kQBFShOuD90bbwixeO7W@RwZfFpuAlhaFjB0uIRSCy4fAaDvoVyFSgtKKLzPZwGSNhjXCUh1o1rb6wLQqh3Yz4DOttY4rGF2AZ1IBjcFBRphE2F@XPfVepCtuOvWXqcrTqg89O0ynadr3KjTuVydU7hs/KbbQCxXa8GG@7WRcOc4vEwGkEl3CAFFZMW9m8UNdym4dFku0BJqoKngDox0zJSc1bcb13GFY/I0Gdiszn7KKN9AXoJ7pbcvKcMjCrtcVpDr2oQEvdl2M6cSSDxYSw@cd0dAp9hqdkyKaF@pnbfsXoSXyWDBsO4foUV5G9SCHdx@pt1DdMNNnDSDlqeFPlrZO/nDbjXqrR@M0Jkt2gICLrPBbs8TZ9dsgYMeWeyN7bMSYtdyROnPfR3StnX95VyGdR19bkn@Htcamz36OPPGpkWhyCMdFz5KvFanAXbk0FwBkEJ95GDC3fqTMwJSQK0E8HE8qoyIDWjRRJAH2DwDKoszMgvEaJ@aVwuytI3QFNNGIi5Nx@lmZG8kvuWPpkYNm9zfPlxPbn5OpGfTY2y3/EXHSosQyszIJmaGAYoVtnxycP9oyMZWq6XiO/jCk4FuqPeHYKAsq7QASWjha@wj3px9hGmSaLaLkBXA@2j7aeHRl2FRg/6B@SOvGNguAnwTOLiSxe8ab2LEnIJzScQ7rfqTohGIbCEkYQyEbDKSvyf21zV8vGsQItPESWB3Il7FaCtmZSntvla9mCgIbkVosS5sgrjRW0zQVxsU036G@pGuHQMGhYJjVCCRoNJb4DLQWSRtVpVvgcA4qIC5g6QuqJIVUG72GtqUPU18AaRhiD4yWtv2YtGRiq3UpurQNHmMn8DOi9/BC5CWAbtGSuz3UxQf7/RkTkOfC2Qc@7npE5fO31RYZvcIfI5Z4oebJgipkP7q5b3SS3vwoJOhqyEpmKwIAFLiPnHA/w2S@HE@UHnwWTkkUiyi5DoGpKcXV4SDdmmxoiG4FIZr4yrQPsExvTEgdI88Y8GRKUD6q3@RhLss01BDNSs5ZVaDOEivHJ2TTqVzsRoOi4dmvapQ@s9oaudkdU8SoRh6tGpdTMlbkKl21LUEAceV1uHnTfq9Om2IgIte/gL6uRBE@q@LAxCpK4c0YPm1lfkvLyJZClbf3sqjbTgZtLrO2JK5RJF7nc65rqoQATcFxY8V0QDJoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHFx7WVR9Ov7j9gS3f19tP7zP3@zB/S/WTtDGChw5jF0tGHoxpqS@msry0@KL3RbXbF8gnxqmToRhlx3gezqLhRJt0LHatC0CC9JMPyPcEnBr3Fom3gDqfGWZsYx5yuCwXN1JqsW1Wxgmd11ca/tx@JZ0fIPKHY9IgIXgkyDEhHr4pVgzPgSTETFRjZ2N1LBpilGjZnX@3A6mfI7CK53VqI5xt9tfdOPmcnrHdVQ@M71W6rc1U@nPUcanw5CObWwIu6i9LQGLIE44C8Ht9G5uvi8gHwnePBcF20xtCnn9LirVXj21BtLHdLCe/yNOsLolhxci9/XRTH9w3uhYz3VTItu79kSfejQUPzdEAruNZUiRDOvkdnSO3OUQYYf3srCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldTo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WOWoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatjRwHpO7U0t2F65YmvsAjWEZYNyPtDxvPzK4D4sCYqUVZ1YKhIzJgEMsMtsYtMsLtxHSLbH8wV5ExOE4iha7VLMDpTnDL6Jo29R4MjW/VxA2xkUYiO@so1XXO8bdWfBiCasrvq0e0Nyuxeg/mJFldS4dxfO1wsDQ5iJOPdzTUc9Mz6LaasKcrEZ10rZX@y10gmPaLTuPd1aw903I8dkz32wg0cIEK/L66QUdpaeq2RJPhUfctPCjY47CoUN0aOFahNFB0uK2t9anbR77vP9@Xw4UcSlXv4FCB@OPYqv9cy9dPFff0rgqiA4su7m@NOG8ZYlexKX/tZX3pQDHAhbvVJXuUKVFKWeFTfWsyxiWXc30ePH@GoWMdaYOhYzwncRqkO0xQLoFj4nIR@2fJLXd7br33Y0o3wBbvKkSkck8tAwYrut@oUqZl1A9MoWYy78@i@tbUmBorFY3DzisDj9XfomS8P1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1htfM3wvrHGcxrdbmYlumV3jblFmmamNQfoeo@r8DBzP0HEzxcCejpdqdUk7s49uJ9lwHHRpp7eEHYZ8KB8q3SEpLcnnnkG/WzUmruHhBrFaPpPJ@AJMZMVl6eU2TSobpn1l8vtSxuSzyHkRF1fZ3IhzdR5ElugWxLUsSFun2FPkclmxTduYzPH@nty04zjWh9QUMFU8MOyAtirRVtvbauyGuOMfImGLqQsPJzw6/XWTFny08XVLoA8qzbdVenRJ6L1qU8JFzxEuSC2/3j59E1lguisXPNyKc0J88621Xpb0Z0NUuSQXb@11XEJ1Ooal88eskLsNXlnO3gpvmWn4i7W4uMuXdBdL8bFrTGk8B2KZPdBShsbIoNdbpHy9hyYy/MfaSDMHf@uCZ4bRVWb7RnddhLEJfMHG@9IackRYmjg26FcT3OeHeoqFO0l933UcOFj1W0nkg5E@MLjNlts45WLCAnfTcLVu4Vw9dVHhO2i6kGxhjGN9k4BOdWrMveC5EuDTeRfqdTq6e7rtWufv4hzoe/T2dVtYbw6x9tAZ2kNjyPeNh2/rOge0xwm3sXMb6oD1YIhb2cbjpS3uUXpajmW9Dz2RNXJG6Tj9lTjt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PlAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjfOWbQycTndo3oW0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a5IGZNJD9FbtkwgrzuXsb3UouHH@DhYV@n@7BEf1kLHLfLKqhk6OpYtjfXTrsdnQ9HFKjghHOmN/PB2hY6/V15PzckCaGQvUzi9y5cl0LEOd3/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tibSslIR0FcsnIgMCjrst2eZ9bpItls/y2DqFoKQmjyL6UDyG3v/eHZgfNyLwt@C@1r6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491ZNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBVTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohp818tTLtV0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr6wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a65oFdRkV20vuhP216e6Z359CiVb19jQYgNfhnSjR/vxbQW8p/rA7D5eqogQSZ/A/k5P/lhq/uh1sy7Oh6aHO5pCxy0TU9jkeCPGVtcGvWFFzOvz9qGxikUH4scgV8ZeNbfujOd4WmxOrtum1c0JzbL6z3Wq47pNYLcicT4djaee/1iNA@2Zis5Cj07J3zs3Abj0GlgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFaQwf1BcONdJ498wLWfAvlHKMBDaQAhD4XxFw3kAw/Mz3JDj2itaIuX9nsueONEhubxgr6FujSyTTNuc3D6bM5ng5pzgiYXhIweeUFCe4F2@/6EQpJPVFHlyt6y/OJp8x/gOLe/YmbpdA52hvZGoWuDnauwFu4/xRIeD9lLOo1pa17Gge4HDWtlluo49nUju1L51VCjcOipU0NpUpBmwxNf3nz5PRlsD7da@SwoN7JEtXGs3DFxrZKYNgth6ProcO9AlHnI7SUe0VfiONLtozKlL7Pqhs0rfeTaHAeS9FSZg/tPRQ6OLy4Z35v2p89SxHRiNxsAoR0cGP/O/tNFjdUJM9gRPtQN9endmc0xg1wxCXNrQx0YH6tdauN5nLOKAH@oTfc1QRHODpP@Frjvbiml1DPcVTfpF3OtU2mWEHhsz0i3WNxjeB6VJt8tFYpyPW@ojSys23thxbH4nbpuBh/r0dq4CQwHd3n@hXMaN@EvzAiv1s@WiHp7xXSJGjxulWFdW1@g4Fr/fsifJNvmeAN01DU95gjYOyK@QYxJIX96tPKR4Kw9ZqEYgyZ7pHi3Sr1Y1FiDV2QdsARrqbtfBlTDfccvunIhhgjvYdLi3n28c6ADhZ8Cx9O7UNxZ6F1rWqDOi21qFIVKbR0YHTwV1yJrHRJ/drEw@M@SbMojs6AoNAATsCjt1gSWegTaSvHvYWtKjlqlqjulGnHrtcjlt1pFs0@i@0XHWzCF6Leaml8KhzMqn5FwzVx3pRjSLrOh00n1lT1reugYCjWVIk6ELOr8yuW16OzCzsmI9ZDoycJF5eRVmrejqeEMqrLN6PT1krq4h@bb@gJeEdv@4fCjtrpU8ETz8Hz74RIFBuF3IBaZHgHXdvYIPyE9d23@8Twt85niTvjk7BLzxFMA6doLFykMSePCega6tdYWA2rOnFp99GET2XY16pI5JZIVZkixi1xNDMuwziQzBzW6WyOGHvpRdtN47MXqSbwcBVxqkJ8H5rzCa/1yxgBrljbjZU1U4YWeFnL/9cxVxzwPOAPKWM5HGHj2Vsffs4MnhiTz21JXj0@4QT0fckOOWDCtopUxkSuqV7kbWO/l2tJ7pTZQHx6q09@RAxghr6M1XNCR44Mrc0mPtvGdgxVXR12pBGGpMVguIj0@ePkktjmiyxN7QdUZGMhq8d3ycxpMmnxyvDI6mfgS9o@/M1iY/2FfV5Irm@9ym1cF13HNFTusgnRigjUJjfMztstwpXHWdsdE7mY@Nz2DwRA7uvWf2hbWF/FQ/MwfYC1l5LaGoo7KyXMglIzuzQdk23PC5rj5PzTFyyy49FP5Yux0FJYes4mZXSw@3rfhfl2JYxt@J8GGJ1MzN1hq1I6zo3t8XMVVV19H5WO9DvbL82spajrBqfdhyzt5jKdnwlRcp9JIm0Kok88595EVpBKxbwRtOz/ue4Oys3QZzG4DQu7Cyw58b9ly3JVrLuk28qEBq3NR2a5RvGO@xIBXu8DlDY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8o6MT9xIkr29Bwd3JTjyaXl7rI8/fc6e6R4aIbk9YhRj4z0wXkhGrySct0ILeGuXU3sugNJuhTcYr@7PFXasuz3Hns/uXoSjM6g4tJNx4RAWvlEkwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6t3mZ0V978EIczX5KDo8ZpfEDvvv3PVDWTIdND@FQz/PWOmgk6OEugS5@jPbto0MlByBq6KLfI4JFcqY0@MWa4HYXPBq9S6leOb4Vbxr5icv1wcltY6Zaw3C353QhDT5aVM@otAPO3hLG8HAY/cazzoSPv6a7hrdh/vBKh2wpSvqUg5Qh39q2l08Ki714v4uPRBf@xsrWeGBM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyZ6isfSb4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c@NVZm9FR/szqAOM3pyiBggsZwSkcibgYvL5B2QOY17IHJ7SuyB85kn95uUczCE8@r9yKY44fT8XqMgTfiJymus/OliJ@Dzuyce@wBHo1biOkrdH/cH7faf51My8KJQTQz@vhkN2hdh8eKFslxgcUXz5a88fDo5PA44ucas9k6pVeardMhV4Yscv30JLeU7Xb9xdkKYq0/bwTiBvDj8LlWDuLM7pPjmywB1bfhZGQFIZ/o9mLGdKnCes6EThquDHw2n9E2ypU1PeS72FaFud0V3kuKPQzIpgl5e0q7jZb12@11rfLE@ILWHkAMYhMulnCgvuElY5YbBhhSkrUd1TldCD9L6B6Ph6Y9Wxk0WpeGdpEmXnmru8EuO7acc/YktCq0jj1oq4HrZ4a9jjmtOqwolbO3S2HZayLVunrhXy/xH@uq5ME6Qe0az8ANEbdxE0x/1FUeBS@fack7439yHES/O@6e5eD8fc@cju6OTGBTqbsjurewv@sAzbuj4cc@ToeOa98dNWhOlcoDYx0S/HgxtM6oaXov7RsX4sfx@SFoTw6@H5BI2FDw5PLHmqInutGAc2ITDZhu0ultiHt5yTb8E9MQIAZnsP0z4mjn0LSnBh7y5p9wmdQ2IZtaTc2X2Q5@HakC@lmSckQvsiYX5NVgmxf@8edKRb1iGzUmVkTmH0APjUNzA8cAF02zQpmYdKqyzQmEbAaHpxl9q4NdMprzASVTzWfgTVaiZiSq/vFyQGnz4tnBs/3jk92T58eNTOvKP34eFMK2IbfAyMVH2Z4IZffJBrIkN3dOZg8syI6@I4JzRV5QLobfJlouWm2paItCiTuYZvPCthWFTuAr0hXgJ4k8NwpFjgheHHZQYqof3/hChR@GpzP9UEUctEh5Qp1VWGZVxmMd5KJN2w@//ikvCsVPvVXwY2@YsW@hGhriwHF6fo6ewe6@ghwf7R48eX60zwIEF43m3OxNhrVynhsw51ZBoJ76Jm1JrLG4nyQOdVWrxR/FgTBxOc4qZDOBjIdDO4doAXXQ2oKfeoslNgk@UDAeVoryn7@pXMVl3F2fhLjxAKk4ZAtNnhrKxsYGO4FGwh4eHXy2f8QQ//2H5I0kQhDsBA9s/9mPevzzG4FBpeAzd@6IhBgySCNEjTYElgwWxhaQ5tR1x@s/dkefuyCTBuF3NsIPBQkCfYYF2u052UK8ZicvSaar@Mf5fDOGQUbUhAKT/biQgyYJXY@dmZ6JBhUQhz5aCFxu7Lj3i6xiymwXv@SH3wvU6VswgPrUnnArXL4tnhi0NDlkOWm2ScjyL8eIkYjx7Q1o7B0D5Fvm2SZIS5MKewUtERdLKtzghiTV4zeSBKAr5JJQJopEvGFS0FOarvLuV/@JMqgycE/A/R3fPcs8gLdf9t/64P4V7n6hYEO7aYJwgUsUITQb6peAIxLSH2kf@YChzY2cLAiHlhIDvsrMEVTTGVEdo/Mc@F0CdryAk2h8BpUGzQ1qzDduwvMz3FYC7ZZWFAWbFOpcMh0tMWZ8n@c1@6WFfCGnKoCkdBYApA8ODPAAOweYTFagmwhn5rj2EuT47e1tJuLEi1ErVHnNKpv2i6z4MkR0E@IK50NErsEgDSRZpICwup8MBp@UmsSkyL3iahwZV8@BUYnCcfTCd9snhMgSQCxOIwMt2M/wW5cTEEd8O7wd/Dpk5GM0mz4gSYUxiVxJUfDNgnzqTKD5QCddfG6KmwXBfc58BEQDlx7/AiyZv8X2KN/sWYvT7MFXb/y@JiMP4KCymeuDabRuxc8RxDGCqIirmm/jBWtOmnZL4W2TQTP94YrGbIP7l5TBmjbLy7170/hp4rrpUiQWu39sOzjD9AgKwxKaomUVtZBcFCmXW1kkv0R@NlActLB0CdkBmwKW0TXMV87Y293bP/jk8NnxDQOfFDN@PRrw/fp2qinJ6UYrdMSjxVqukgePlOOnDx4FFbFAuhDhxsD4/ZKot5VkMXGMIBcHka4XbRWG10u3HuPPuamC6/hmtdtQo0Q38FAzH5AvHQaQHtGRvuuZa6VV1Mrnb0NpAU@JgN7j57FvoJpIXlw1Wtv1ph2L32wJKzrCi5i8hZ0AXE1va1PBxn6zcFiw8NvMJ/jVOy/aF7Or@6K4mUX7cWgOYuKcLizs@R6RgEh5g2yARQqyEkRd2/sOuYy@sAOp8W9Hc8NzUbNaEYQLmdsoHgF1EnyGGrnIwoqtb8B1qHtDy@wIgTkzbsg1sDcZ2nDlpsgSScH/FgrPOOF/mHpWmcm08y@RRG5HsNLsNpuwAbykAB0apbtnU1C@nzljbhufdng8NALXkQPs9@GUzwgZ7JPpCOL16XFk0GobcG4JEgMl4yGqXJYCLuGbhJ2l0Ogu5NdAw7B@weVRL5@YJeWhMeuZA@DtiWQaONpHqtpiodlYLDSZibXjItXZohZu7Yof4yn7KNk/yHbwbIGA3tBl0@4Zs0T8PJ6stCB/9I@ff34WT4qr2hLZMPaN@vauGzMO0S@qt3MSfeL3zsBS8CpuUS7f5BLgdx0wN6oXfJirXJaHnkAfWqyh5H48cZ@AE8SIRH@kj1lianODhDKj10QzYafJUptU58ZObZZKkUIFDwqQGaXsk4uP3wndnrOEUsNvcYKvZ/fw8cYcs4Yqyy1wUyZJtokfzNsDiQtNdCYF0IEhSYXA1rAJgZoBGPFOIvMGDmkwHOLCg8w6rgim74fRooSDNKFSs/o9FvkA4rLkKJbLFb9Cl7limUHru8kOZQXA3uBzgVwP1PVtFQHNQP2VhdiCkd/keDHKN8YReewbOQJ0YhEDxYHtIwawFuaDu0MXf4l9G/oKyAeVyvOTR@1SUhFZaCxp4Jo9XDTjNvZDFc//KhJ0U2UparzKNbqPMRmapWxza0xoHfERdRjxGkuNRcngm/YNlGVv0TZV9dZW7yf0awFi5nAA8A@VtgNwaEo0mE1bEbaa2f/0pzEUNhKbqnrads9S8XymCje1mmd59tFmU5I2G5na/U0dtKjJ61kTdHJlK/fwzBj2ewcDpSmKLMtyirJ1cXERf7T1zHyRZwWpZ2qF17P5VbaQfT27yqql16djtdCQX89aYqmWPm2xZ8@@eNt@mxRnZ/PXYjOhxfYOL0U1hyp/rFJmFzuFbOy0DOon5MvYKXsD12mf4T@53/Qibh3dnT6osHGRxZpNoLgqFkVFacRb8E/q/ku4uOLfqMt1eaf19m2yoeuT2ZyZpjn2ej34OUOQILXkMQN9@R5wep5AYU16kgaF12jWvzmfkGdstmsMBtN9va7heWP5frs6N6ePJk@/8XlwPcfrzVEk2Rv/C72pVEKSGivmKSptPR/Db/3@2Y83rtIXz9rbf/atkWJs4OMQH9@5eoruYzX/0cbGRw8e5HJpTdO4@9k3nv387u5u7mE6/6yR38lJmY3tP/2TjQ1N29aUjZbnqa144/T0C1HL5ET5z34n3n727OueV8/@n998W1fxVoTbGSsCn4Ary1Rw4r0EPxVlrPe9Ym9i0MrV2Jz@2rHA/2KDqfWd4n/53uHr2CRW15TPXXhOYq9jhVKMO8EBb9ng7SxWj21jtMJVbK7UajVwFv/Lv4X09U8ADobMt@FWzwewCvNYXapRkstYvQAOVdMg3//7m9@MYMjZRI3EuOC6zxpwibmiJu604Nqia1tAI5RSRlGCePZkODEcppbuqffwxYQXeNgGWvM3Js0Yfu2cHd5n7KiRSqVacluCS35Bk0SKqmpNVb0H7ED6aKtWk7YYN7OZzebvoanwJE1pDRwYMY17n/9DXLFVntWfGdyRECts3H/5sF6HMmXr2a16ii6/I1GfKpZEx7kvsjR7GQcVpNF6@YRx28B1MVPSxHQ6fb9N7zOklTQLWxJe/B6LhT7YZdl1v6UkEMX3jX14vNg@Xn/@v/359//8e/T3ffr9B7TSaffMvrIFkc6gS9Thul@pdOt1se6KF018r0M7ylRKlZLSvmomtoADtY6Ymvn4Mp7Pxo/5l8hVxppJSg0XZVv3s8f3emzhXec@9aifH8AjkwfzS0GOJaqRO6TajXgwtPr7maXGWb0loUBUkxpqId@SeKp6cJVZ4z5Uk6gVy2KrruW1Q3a/PeMXG256zImBZlgI6OjjW1@UrR6GLN7qUa9YPUhWX8T50HghvkKs0VBaBg0IgR@7v1HZKFUKFU1p19df0DSjrxTVMIxnXuwsFl6csrEFQWNh07zuF1RF@MKCFsw@JB5IRu/DfKmWsgVVrPourc3EKjQSLStpg7aYUcWwt@H8Plwb8Ef/cIWveN8gH9@boty8NlhF3dKySv6jwr6G4@sdVxRXAcYJ1u10Om@6HZA6dL2jd3V1ok/1mT7XJ51pZ9aZdKddhl1meUY/6@SdkjNjvAHKUiybVzdj96hRv21ssCPOhVosFVzN1J3Xc1lu@05yOPiTJGcWE2L/AFdd1VS2BeNTBm4glJETdGb8U1WBxUDQumi93Wq83YIOWk9tE3Ns1SUfS3jI7futlHR11QB3ter/b9dDZ5Uu7oLCta5Sqe0XdZA@XtQbKQD5wgcpS4yAyu16a5tCwsz83Pzg7RbIL1Jqu7Fdc/boJ1MHkeI5J15w7rcA8PYSsvfvp2Rw3QcA9U3oj8lUalOSNnBsbPhjBURu1VNBqRCHBEgLFxc/4w8UPejFV9tX9avG9tXV9jb8b9P9yn@C79X2jX96LK41cRbhLWQtzYZSbypNn1m04F1W6ugjK01w1OEJ8RpZrdRqoAMuufXf5r@cXtxDH0S5JQPWQmyLbcXQZmQ2tiXEXr778n/BX/Pdl7@P8iKDP6MixC6wWytbqG2WudIJN2Y/tdlTftngxl/wij7o8bSOnja/2bggpSgvZVbhc/4JtVRIyjgAt51@G81QyOwlRL3B@5iolQpiO6XONRbbFgtFYnc/d@OKx@P/6KVWLsb5RA3aUXjped7TCJYLPCFyVcuoknpZ558K4F91@blV1z/6uXWXELssM6MC9Ol6jFNGiEFDiimKJMGIVd8e4U57XCuRUC09q30hPd@VcB5Fn9BKWJfPEdQO9mvlcp0v82w@o26z9XAL7ir8729AOVizD3Gb/Vp3BBJws5/Na000LB@TOq/x78kb/GMnXfw7eo1/7OQN/h1N8I897eDfyWv82@3g38kI/x68xr@nb/Dv@QD/ml/JZtWquHlBpEmpZfVqcyYSiaqxnXrzKxN3XrEMu2H2Wv43k7K5MkvGml8xZl1jPKlwz378J9/91rfitVpcitOXaHKq4zI1WQXqQ4m8ePV@XIjV2Ka6qWasTDejdtQOOEyWcVlmmBmqPVBU2irLGCwzz8xZZuSoPXAZ8JcBl5nps8yAZeyMDREhFFyTdmaCrj48BvDXB0Au/Jm4cbSjZroMMrJQaKOPWCJ4cF22m0KDxZn40gBdU1bljFwwW/jpn4b48mVT2Wpp5RKTsVHJ7cbLZrwlNkU0B6@Vc6wzNzaaL0UYmjMib3zow2KeBwpsNaY0mwonE1CAqHh11W7vf/qw3VZwGGo@dQ4X/4eHo@jrrf@jQ@fpoTNy4P/w8BC6jlFP3U8Bg75/vwYM23/sxOrVnWaF2H7A@mPK9k6znpXQXUgBN9fQL/WB1wIiPOsbTSF@nkDd4xzVj@rn59WzKrnPg1dwtKuLCEE07vCfcJ3DEBeoI@dwnZ2jg97Qef55M3Rxh/L5OXh9zkDvCv9BwYu@/lf4N//b@n/6nCVZotFKJi6uthN0JfEvmby4urjy7/VkIuG/JLbhDz3gHZNcXNXRSZEuwNVIJFvJqyvuB/dEcpsDrEM223VKu4gHw0IszJKy5bfEf90nZO1fzXgV5F6uW@cz1I9iYpXpi301zeYsk0lWO8GXLnCVWL@kzQvJKn3mcLPTUFt/@jv0NZOdJEXK56pVdYvxFy2nVau54K1YqlZLwctmIlG@edUzO2oB9I9cLpmsVuFlJwCbgVdI22BvU6zGmnBv3bvHMylpl5cBzGyukMqoGUwd5JSHbA1P7/oM9@LgkD4EAqwmH8Mv8HBWksjQZ4TwU3VxsSLeu5foGbg7ubezm7x3TytnLi9Dn/EYvNQlr3a7Z7rtNvpnLy/Ftkj7YMp5eM@ULi/VTDmlxpOOm/gUv3EIWSUklX2k1SnXMrBxLVeEYB@B/PZ2IVevF3LgUyjFk7im3kD0W4BvXIxXxdgFlUEtFTkHFKvoHd0fBH0ZBwV2cRWjCmW5fDIBjDQJMuBVDP9c5Ll8uMnnk0CZK5HHVMtlHjXJcoVEKVX2/2oboJWDkMP/UFLLpnJbxa37IPPinzdbdSFPrl4YNfWqdmFUcFb9qtr1vxaNxjSMe/eyZSBRKVNtCu32w92T3Xa7JooiCkpwQ0/i7gLaGHHjDSp5vtziFKlU71M1q6U8g/rkcaQ4jBCsBERXtK28WkIiCWYfbeUASQSuLW2wDUGjJ96EMqfcBniCOgOZ9@BiPdZhA7zYAJU3ZjKLLmYxHk73bjeM5PDLDw1fKS3pd4GPEV6C3wuzvInCIP7sye7e/kla25ZYTHu0u5fWjp8/iKn4ml@8U3AW34/2dx8ePocEz57s7x7vf3zw2f7zZ@DvsfPFFTB9/754Rl0r3s/Z58Ir941uGLoxNYz2@XR6/pq9Ms22CZVpTaFQzsBlntGGsoz1Rbmq8Ouanv7qle6O6WLvfvjtdz/879799nff/fa33/3293/y5fe/Db8fwe@7/Pndf1PO4/0nX/6z3333W78Nnv8Bfn8Evx//5Mtf/yb/0fsfw@8/Rfz@2P9F4vGfALB@@Sdffu93fvLlr/wAfv/S//3g5u9Xf7z69/1fWP/DdN/73dvjfPffwu/3OKwg7nd/i/vh80b83@LxfuUH7/7Fv@P/f@r/ofO33/2LP8ab//JPf/Cn/@ndt/69ppX@9F@/@4XvvfuFb737he@8@4V/rL379X@tZqK33333/T/4qz/8vb/6w/@R/n9E9997n/93P/inf/G//sX//hd/6P9@DL9/B64f/8W/h67yt3/wQ/z/3h/87R/9EP//53/1t3/wa3/7y/8TOX6DO/6ff/lv@P2vf/U//s1vfuevfvzNv/m1H//Nb/zBX/0fv/J//fp//Ov//vf/@p98Cz1/48d/9Ue//Jff@vZf/sI//8tvfbnm/u1b71@@h/@X/wA@74/n@8B5n3J9qM@XPxM@fx9qLHKBdgKt@5fe/fovQgP/F4y9@/aP8Bga/Nb8/0hTKc6P@Nv/BxzazTJjSAZc8Pu1d9/@LpLofwASwX9Ir@@EL0sh/OU7ixcg62@uSPRLP/nyn/8OvcWMSp1WbXDsLmml1BboN1vlsj9@@ws6kOQXl6GFAPycvoMcainsO8jb3v3wm@9@5x@/@@FvvPvhL@PgLeXK6d20pN6xGgYR8@8RDyMW3iceRvwC80/RFJuU@gLe2Bd@4BdffCG0LxU873j/Eny/IC9@MR6E5yH9oCAM/fGAJLtkUbfvzPjOTd83zJmxxsuXLVxvBT/MPUWyx1YgGuWzbJbyEZsxvqyD/hBptkXOGd7JF4NnAt4W/wvnTGCpmT/dC8/UwkkOP52fBXcKecgmNQsXk0hWY1w62uI@tE5M@ebKDEswm6VmoASDA3JIQdADEMdrtRQmrHF84JWjVi8xQiWVqkG5MTVPk26XEMTsAUGBlLXUEWtv1WY8YQrh1QNypAT0OhJVTUyVag8hw9rsIUNYCJzAvnxZq5dqszqCe8vpkZqlHhBOCKyWmtXfwnuNYEI6IfbwLaBSqqVS9RJmiIXk1ZNu80rKU@Go7CmW8usAnrjdf@c@Yx@JaknkiwQbSDAeG@@pRWyMCNEhvJna8otD/4GTfltE8A3Kys@F8fAdkk13uLiKEQCuJMmyzOCH6@877D4EzzioFGULjxSHkKIWQS0g9GA4P5QSUlS/KXqB/GO1rQ@@EBgWZnNzU4jVxax4KBPpFIW5pxU6@4DbAVG9qDCxUBbR26CDIAEukL5K@W/GcWEtzjhg9lGK/@7f32IfQTHpufATmJTKOjknxqFsp1KiBvDrTkp4AWqJAO2UAF0K8qxGC3kpIZ1mTK7FMIwdHh76SJDHi5qQgmauZVV8x@Wk6XQagxSynJbTaf8p05M8ZN8hU6j/lDeRuPQRcKZpuSpoT1WGXiyq6qigAqPn27dvoVZof1XlAJRP5m@10nIlCgQPbvbFsubBgSEtVxa4Zs7UQo6xBE2xwpVkSYEl2FZS4LvyORLBlYhrpVKc4gH15cRWsPOuoFJzwOnVWB0RDS6uEpbyySBw75DtHT59uv/pybjVYoJBHzU32mPX6Rqel8Cw3U8f8hMZWrmQjDUaCPqkoiGDEfYrGWLGBw@PDo4rjBfar4IEIValdVW/mGVViI3Hn2/H/J1HIn6XzxGP8V5ZlC2hlbOQNFYXYl0DNQtcMEcFuMqqwlNv8MCZgU6fFsW0WkDNLkmTykz4eWfK0GosNzEDfQrPacjb20QBoX4h0dIFOqG2CkK97u/ZY6pQP94/gQQnh0zVMrJQ/4LNZMxQuhLqVs0y7MFkuImb38RmRoyUabORSeOfls3CXc0V0mq@2NrYsC4kzLNJ1XaBuxiv4PVCwmJ8FS4mfFVgXwUvuCAP3JrI/H2hB4dVf3Me2mdL8B16opqHbpYUcB6bgxPG0asKrXt5IUiIbXzjGxNWr4N@LR08EmLALYYs2J8mmT15KFM196auQaEDxnrmZyZ@cFHumd7Y0ufQdYAasaurqz5AOnjEtLpGrzxFD@9XXfLpgPtqpgsxu1KpvVVzRUE7rVTeZjVNAA9hS8ENcBvQAGgfwZbC/6oeZJLNlhTgVKoowiObzQo4dywIFUNgtFfkbaZWk3gbzOZU2ioi4Dc89FlNCy8/7uyjRdxshsfFEAhgg4nLMkFYkYf5bwWB3oBouDuOvhhd9Ttn5t69LE5iZHOZcLaCSsyuoG42s7ksUlz4/y88gMVXc7bH9WxG3VbG4NTBmdtWdHB2wJnfVjrgNMFZ3lZMcE7rWTWzrUzrAhO2uYVWhgZgauLEmKFBaO4n1j3D6st4tqgmUgaauO1bPK8HCeu9Ws/p0ufeqz3ZtG3DxePaPEEuJ1YdG20H1tCKCB1wZ4nkhTCondOhcsGoDWQ0R@PauiX05I7Tm8veZG7hKR3LcWtxEAfjQcACugFyCM597WSzuUqDteSxM94RtHwx1VAzMIDgTy2ltfSGsVMsVnpy1zJ0dydfyZfSPTwA5C9x7eQzlYH8xdMnjyeT8ZFBp4J2cmVIgAbc0NTSTqmSz7caDVFMNSibFn6smrMnaWMD@rSh9yR44gKYJ2mlFiTumW6tFo/vZFVNUivZTOlKWBAOaY4lrAuYNIUlSyPdL3wOULEdG5hNJa2nzQuiQqXf719tXaQWL4J@IfE3oM@VpKc7F@FrVYrEq7BpWjIXgeCj94HcF/7aXkXU8iWx2qgu3osFsdq6Eu6PjJ6p42GgZubiZqoCMGUONQYZNZlwVXEdZ1LpGH3HNRYRs2ohiMgRuhkhJ16F2TUzmOPFzewKkUizi5tQcnnxKkwVoCVcXQHdObGB7L753Tptmm2o5VxrH1gQNJ/twDIvRou9eCHEto4@y9brUNUXuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1GG/KuUK@BJ0tU8jkNQ2g5MqlcvEK2rWivI3Rh/fY3kXQ3iv06YGEXuG2Mxstlnz7qWldlLISxyORrF5dxd4KsY@OPtNggFx7JWDQ/UyT6rVsvgyuLLq0LCDMBE2TtKyUVSU1i/93ODT8f//4GvxreIdUWU04QYM6n8KwCUO9zZ6gYY6Jw04c/DTTgD0wumti7A112tG85zqe9/eI80C3T3nQQ5NbsQ2DHuv4fTpvZE6Ga2I8H4/QFo/h/oNB2B91AEFkhzzCA7i5luOsilBkz5@tKeXT0G48EIMbjofoRwcfPz6JPE/2d/ceCwX24PDTh9ceeT9Snj3Zf3QSvhZ5aJA0H4L4@f0nT66/@o/c4fOj/tRx8Sc8OnyeW9xCLzwwK@TgWo4UehMQ/4avJFiCRAGKWL4YOFQBj1ncA@X4nu/MFxbODDo/56eBTS/c9s8PhleEk@CIsM6Q03YM1uUml1BbJ3OIviyvFsuCMGa2c86KGdZzLEt3mdPvb4DnUMfjjgYKtJaFLRGzPndcq3du9owN4SmerCyr@GFzREJ4DEBG0y6Z0gBhBo3rwqhmM1yW6lhTg03HbK0nPNALna45GMIYfO4EEYSOrjP4fegF6Y3oNbndY8LzIL8bIdbN6ALodKW8KO6J4mN9oterrlH1MpXKvXvqM1csi2MYk3VvYOzPoNmy59CNdHeeFieymHvE2gNc2bCcMeog3rgBQntZa7R2clq9lMlnS3/9mz/6uz/5tUFNbWb2MtL2ztMn@QowN5BjGYmqvjgrk2KjlUv5UjmrldKlcimXVwv5fFrV0qATFsugFmTUkloo5ctqupQrgxySK0Novlz0hWElkH6VrQqAtbv4qe1t0o3kIShBfCGSvUnoSRbTw/cpEw1IIwqohk7o8PiWWYMhlKkZli0ygKizLos9erSXefRIFB/gC27k2MuIYg9f8qVMpvhAFA0K2SuhTCU6PE0JjRaKE/6SyTwAIk85ALT3L4pDfNkv4ISaKJr4srf76BHm08cXDdNDtFMewl@s4KUI0Wx8ARmdALwOoUG0XZ5PjhDdxxfMEkMe8ZA9CBPFjwN0MOSIR@MAHgcl3d0VxQP@sruLIXtU7DxH9Gv4skuXKLrwAo1fFAfgGLjQ7USxA07sAqLYBVd3roMfftYcTcLbE10U55w8SCBRnFFsvXsqiu3AH7P5zMcmj9St0IvKS32fXsr4J4pagDRGy4YvWVHMhS85KNvjx5/pw0nPGPBr7vJnF0r6@HFWN2fT/Uedjz/uDAYdd767//ERBu3tPQZ5ZD51O4OOn7DThsuBVHuPNf10NL9@QakP2u2Kbq0M@lq7ndPta0HtedtADCHVa8DMvwaY0ai9B0F7j9v39VULyQSwjb1/BM8OXg9G8Hygd3hQcFEQPWedjljF5q8ozYSAGgMuAWN3PAVuaqdHetd1qvg@q7FMGoWWeaOQaVUpgI1A8s9UrzC8n8C7jrM/yYt5Y1bLtGqzWlHjO5H6CbE50/KmmN4Y7ajlfGVD31G1XGpWQfsVTj/O4pK6wxLqva03LPFpckcDLUBs7uxIYkNt7WhqqVIovtiaimKygvedbLHyJpGJZxjDW7JRbO0U85EUxWJKV7RKsQiyGNBkAkN6Bydl2onEuaGfJpOILU0RQBGorGxO5TSr/cQsPatxvNg8WZ3V1Co3hcwyN4D10O7@tDtxXA5yAOBmO5kKrsEnRLVcEgEBRUkkkyHTA41dWGwC/fzrJ6cnJ1@Q0Ff3Zy@euQZyr6r/@vHjPfngMHhDi/nyI5RFHVfeQ661FMKF0sDrBLQQ@TEMo6DRBX54TtB1LHmf9s6BQBsEBEZ7ZN96rXzyeAnO8dA55zmjmYUqmUC0uwbDDwqYPabX6uDSeyxBWDE9eU4DeLter7VrI7JEAEUMUn2NkbX9BZgDj@MeGn@g5Bd4ds4PaNcyV9VObRabAZx2jUnqy5HTe6mlutUefkfgQe0BJq624dmpGjXDdR1XBH1arPZ37NrU9vS@8cxw0azJweEmiBN4oC7RZ0ZykzX3MfYe6ipXUt1l9gKzT6ejhC7VO8llL5yZCz2QOImvB4W@oDOeuEvjqtqvscQLiPoa3t1NlujJD5I7uSrQ6QFrJ8Er87L/ss80VshVSddIICzoSkQfLLfOkrX61@DBYZ9WKoCNX9GnABUzA8BmjwIg9ti8qnZrFktIbMaSRKRcdVBrYPJLvG1LotiSpMZlS6hL0udCHfprdR7Ta960Q5@gYZmOqmUK1Rn4qcVcdQjVq7@YVd3aeAoSggWv/oQeP86qV4GoQDsA8@Yy8e4Xv5nclvI17lclUJcWiB5tuV2bVW00agkNo5atQUCqkcukQYuHWzENY75WSKuFdDadS0tF9IUBP51PgydoOSBgJKyEyJiYzswysppWDTWdyLw0ey@T6dMEyC1ENJZMT5x9ezpi4ANVhW2TXuEJ5ElpWxZoXz2H6dsSNVZgGVUsGFB9yMZmeoigjgzdohTJpMSyWwlrM4FxNk@m4/1Gq1LZn42/DkEJ6fVOIVXMpN4kk9XERrLmGa@FelWoI3uhUo83oOX6c53Mm44aUMvgUotapdHoYBGLmXQ2k4XSme3LwbZYF1vpzEZBhSq6YsQ2GOcb0ek/lHgWfuM2St@WAVWnlrWqINNcXLakSWUlv5XP8PlAnlIY@@wNKckSTTE4up2Ix4taPJ6MV3ElYkP0p56BpxE/iwN3jd9Td0QQxsSKWNYwwoI10uncTIAdiGNXAkqFLAfK7YVwdXG1XRe@Ihzjmctt7QX@FV883T3Ev6@AVxleSy@ePj98fvhIYApt9pTbsepGVa62q/AiyfX7QqzCGHDSpm9XStlg7EO3kaa26y/4s4nnBwCuQIaqG6xF27sMEzU39hnaLNhhcSiD7o4ampZtNbQijH3ATYOomqZWcZ0mhicU5DpUhncB@G2n6njc72tsPtdTUqDu32NskNoUiDyx63MBu7XdwdFusENtd2/1jMHmWMFJ6tWBdZCHTk9V/9xOMdMWqzHWFvP@AbnF2Z6cuN0URBH3xMUu4rH4FfzF4gGYF2@Ckz8FsXqaKW8vnQsqB@eCilpbfMG86ima2twWYvfp9KPGTz@yWHj@ERd3/XWZbK7AkuVg2eQr8fuxeDyO6xMV5r2NxVaV6LQqxrPpeDEdV9PsfrxYyFJZqm/EXFgsH7NSW3xTfUEYUxsMjqZ97aUGzT9mO4EHaIA4OwfDcz6P6wEx5eXY@4ZWyj49OLQfuo8ix6Re1GP4tXEJT3xVKy/aG6cqNPusmD1Nx9j9GJ0SEMuAicY9gOCnTAUsgPBMfP7w8KmYQ3pV1Dh4JYBqHH/ItLlxueHgAhALtyW@tT/5OmPjeDYHldGsxWa1nL/fXa3XJXVbQ3t0RVaBQa6vFqTMZZ134zoFFDQIefeLP8jNtkvwrmVUeNe0fEqr19UtjSVj43df/j6aFrrY/2z3CYvjssHf/cnvaMW/@5N/RTvr4le0lKBlizGIiU61UIxdXIwvLq7g4mH5WCvGkcoVk@Dmy1pqrK6oWta27SqrKLq@VUzltPt2VfHjqkU1GfOkmL@ZNFvIS4mEqgBWW9lSJglhl35MLVOCt2BBjUcXC1BRUID9IzOvqfe3d6B8O9mcVt2AJqeGB25Z@LdteGVUbJ@@vGQMXrr13mBgauRSFFZ5K7Htt9I2e4vLWW@lDfayVsdtESoe0w2We7bw2CIuecbrKWUrzkApZPXGVfWqlaL1IlCfXxjGlt281mqbG3huZdlry4Y/Y8ujP0wUeHjwGrwZW688MbGVVJReT7zZG7YNlq9Dg9lSFoeJ2VawCsT/JKmZfPeLv65phb/7k1@9bF@2v9BAsS6XC6oW@@lPt6f21DN69Z8CgFvMygTKMcnHaP8FHaFSzbhxT9NPFTrkLujzUxsVCB4/ULFRqWYgfJkD2@iRii2cocBIldvmlg17CYq2hVYn0qSAkCWxZFUQAkmdKxjuoJsmGGwLLdI2WknhQvgqBoE8wkBJqQpfXYACjxFIIE637VlTd0znfhKUTm2l2T1IAjl8FY1GbpC1DH8wk4CrK1s3k3KUPaIaCZdsZHgemqCEcVj4KiTxzXZbczbW0bALxjRtGD1ljEJ4UkCvAXm3IG@LJ2iTb4JKzyOkGceOJ7JBCRG@CvIUUcEEMYuZ2xChCvzrq0AAKEPCB2y22DbLJtmFmUpVF/Ytr/CEAlrg1AOjEgImQ2g9NGISJK5iPPAC5Qc/FIvtwq9hkHIjngEQDoNvaKiB@oTJ6Q0lV7L68t6gABZZWEtQ0di9ewusajWzl2RUIoR/ao5x@o/qwV6NKwALVM@PehUxzdByaDXwDZsdUDxF6EKrk7jJ0GokKRPx9UoQ4P@9Gy22yGtVRQFVLIBfX7xXdIFkkBjJzuuwy7ZrTNWKSRYi3wXcu4QUHe0P9enm7CNZ@yIIvAIMfxoLPsMETOskOqXqt9vrVkUYaBtT/AYO2pbjzMC3BsKtxyHzO5gEqcNUUBTToth90wVNj3ZaBIYrE1k1ickWhj4JD@LjWo7hVv58Eh@UCmMzeOpogNHPZ4MMR3UdqFBv7NhksZEsSuE5CmgRwKN8Y3cc7al9jt9M8@uGEkcx8sjQHbZ8xJgsUNLH5iktbnXouIZ@GtAmzYyBzLqjHtPKLEENjYzy2SG4JCUihDugMCCNO5YxApSODYMO33kVRRmAEDntkGXCpya0q@EjE0Yg21MecgIr5@apqZyg8WLJ6eMZPW7nJYZyJ3Y/vqvCtwJoOc4ps8xTg8@UJ5as5HgMVCaQ@tNA2cUPCFvB7TpaNo0zNyA@USz4FeFR5M5SOpJ2IzFP3nxm1Y1EG2v0ksYbE2rFMs50O0Jfui4Ff67Am3uBnS2yFgXvcshyDd/CTi2OtjNC01GCbzGsRsaqZFyBGSfEmBhY2kKnMHaNM4Zav4BjDDDNbmCzBnsxlParNABQ34OehQY4J24FLS0BJm4v0YWu5zN4m33EspqAEbkZNN9kGcDAqq8tQ4cwSIrl8CY9qBiZlh2Qr0DvHPUgDG18@M0P0wetG91kHHXRvNmGDw4HHcqrxni3CF7ykRfsHdieqegbEFgADFdgspEQUwA2JSZFDjpMfz05b@0C8ZIKuwkpzRCCT2qAQqKCjiwHLSxGPm4mQMAD3eNfwPDNc56fn8tkM3bqmrLh4Qe/PMfWLWU8MEH0dpSJMRr7n1Y2u8o4gLtwSfw7f/J4ON6ZoXRbK9@b86cg9L2av@kpEe97cRwcz/B7VoMR2ZdDw24eNahHJn0Lr5vw92Dx9qe10hdB@6tg@5NK8SsEwhiCmaXn6W4agKU73dN0/7xX9QPOqEMCcKhFI/BES85u8DLyApc57ocxnAny0TCoY53SOjZAEvkU9yJrXsIg5jx49d/H5gwS2cY523VdfZ6g8CTGxgacmJPYw@Yw7FMIONE6@AU3K2zOGvPWUvJZmBwGtXAXh4vG44SL24FyG9MYPuPhMwif8fDZItMg28asxUUy9LrC4mCrR5ujQUwEMw/iXHF7zIsQggzyOKhU5Icx50t@V/Dr1ih1QG/@BvVYCxoGtIkxENxIKI0XzUazZXvG@VYrpQygsYtECKhxAN1oEU3Pe6EbqW@dWWPHW/Ky0dQsjEo@3ujVHfqtgbcVLGNYQdQwOL1MtA46GPnbTbhA4BcYIKAcBoEoGuxOEmayGto0p0BoOA1xQWOOWMNHpkXSlx/k@4G4xEnPCRsF1IoAQv@wSIAmhLCg5/DPOwbc4XPXgThBXIm@SDdCK3XxVhwoea2rcF5TpUqKYCVJAZpAdhRXa9eLEoRDVTSuBUWKeeXXfxT9jQ9Gvw/9YjX21GD5gFEVol0Fd3iCCOF3F6Iqq9ci9QoYKFu6Zbgwcu1z@dQfrSGbLSVQM3g@WATv3Jx0h4lI5XeTvH7oHKloi5WwKcxrNSjivMa7Je8XAUk5wcNknp9sHjQEPz1nIAAjszKZ4SebRZPNajXOONhsTbLzCJIzQnLGk/DYszVItvxkoD0dBMMLVk8LpFPcgioCPJUPoyAGjUXm6WcGbgp4hRY0cVnFz3PBc6gV@G0IRWxsZ93WytwbEaQjTOsaAGyINwD0@JeiK8J1hqdK4VvIozgpAx7F3/xmwHkFNDBiwVVuZToRNjLSgUHgF1M0DkDfFVMNQVRpahz/MvwnpgPP4Kfe9Mwsx1SXPTPpa3//IJ4tpGykg0akDzWTQ4aMmsxz2zfPGpU5Ymx3CgoOSHWdc4clVgjb4K9M/aRKx3I6ykjHzT34/VjuK4/nyUB/wMUldn/sTPSJk8tVuNJkUrNblT/XGcyB7eBnpyKW5kHW6zmGZ8cnUKldZ2CbnpFmaAT01PDVDsP/9IUQlZN9p@MJgr/NjKuxCJq3KxR12238on27ncDdm8lKuBWdNnNi84zHBdR/wRVJD@zJB3o4TjidV0Z3krwbJn42wU92YnZPE4djPxCnancZ8LAuyP8QOgQJhnnOQnMkk@woSncmCfrcx9AZOQOQ@qaeLGDqa@APFrARIX08JlzSTEeVthL5eAb1kkQ3rSf9pF/74KTsa1pCT4bptWUAS8RIM/c6jZGy7ors2muz48mC/I4/HN/jKL7Ht@NLWvh1nLlqXuOBH5Z1NrGAABEXaGTvRgOLDnyrdwOdJVRCb5SreIL3RrFHm@d6iOkuRN31o8t9aB/p8M2DtxDxz9bR//YKDJLvv2/16dDt2fEc@M0I96Em6EuBXrBGnIDoB0nkPTezC5v2w/fMC@LiR1ofoQgBYiwxLhutSUPHHIPa7YUTyAHgO9o87le70e5pE1uNB67AyT1Ls1NtfRU9bPcMS58bvYQfMx2BG5T4CBQ24lfvV3BkdMT0HK7rJWDsSoahMIwj0Xmkypomo6fPksn1zYpHMcPWQzPlhOHBevph@A3WjFN8NT5bDXpAPB7D6dgzE6c/x/PxnH@wwOKfifP5KB9/eE2iLYy7CQJ04KOnml5km7yNfR4lwiK9x4gQxpWXi4z2xAOIaGLqZh1@GInuLun/293XrrWRLGn@pq4iLeFGZUolCRuMhYUtQNg6B4OHD7u9mFYXUgnUFpJaJT7UtvuZmR97Azv/5xL2VuYe5tdexdl4IzKrsiSBcffZPfPMeU6bUlVmZGRkZGRkZnzQ4FqVKmaUnXSqntkj3rlrxC2uMDwpl1H3Y8lvMd29ec5iNQGWiLDN71tCpiDDsKXZzNkQ5c2dI9bvTckEvONzut4tq0pjhkCNa7KkG3V4u836hetgZ1ynvzhwekd/AfAsHDWEoUzfcKalM68q/nIRDCytRb8hJZ2gWFQUkms0rFKOeabin7/GbTZvbbM51WYz1WY8A9JNWoWcZqpJPQoYnruGoBu2R7dIZ3zC3pn@3CW26X@9fjDEacXnhc5CueOphauFMgnkhXChXMuRUF5oLZS3@CFaKB/ww6eF8l/pIZlbC18WymZaoMCQfvLDS7zXIhy/mwvlzZz71RkFn8LItOsvlOMxpTIv5CdThEiBfpPWiCu2Xl93czQMaWFjpdJT4JjIw/aJz2E8/q9I/5fkW5yWBx9xxvmIC6tFVUotGtaKIe3QsmHSPsyYyWW9mtf2ttkwLC6CZhZpj2fXYfCkhmcX0sJIEMNXvtGgv4Qg5GZ5NkbKWsnuiY5unTiUBzndPlPPZ32glePvx1T4JGmEM67p@ma80iBkAO@HJyrfhucUOqY5xgh3su4MtEDUnxfu6BTGOo2LHn17hPisO12IsM2bIjJKDNaS6aTD8eUcGhv0B2km4a9wQejYdfhQTiYluHeiGksFPTNv@cyvdc8gGOzJ797VHaseUEuJIHw8Lp7ILIvXBZbF@JTIOktTlclHKFgyh2Z42PzE2ey29COXE3Hj8Vpx2zJk6kqTLLnSYpIq@4jtdRmMpPV481pDxK/v276amjc4a8kBgFUzbkXka/879Pe@6O9GoTZEmGhglmI9eymdVq/vXGUnMO8mzU4PID56asudqRzFLSQkp92BpZnfxWtTKj5MPkTJl0Zj6BPaviFbvCf4Bt0m9xYCC1rC8Cr98tMSvfy0dDuhpjWS7pVvlBYfLWk40vEY06Rrd@MqHZ81xPjC59tB97sHeJgeYHvwAI87MJwguczy4WWPrVySuU1iW95ApJbKSgQ5X5fGw5y8JHHPV7fxtS292Gvsb@3t7nygRffp06euXqPHCX6YtThrjddxgcxW5vF6MGPbsuQh5RQuu3EcH533h6MHH3uZKVkiwpqUgYBaMeyn57irZZklzyfmLtWTshZFNaxPyTQIUlIJqk6AJbuj6ToigoSj3KNAAzHqLdHb492ay8mVGo1ecBE2Grx8mazRehXD0Jgbcfdv2QeFy2jI2ZElM9i143CQDbW1p96/rh6qw9c1tX20@Vf1Ye9Iva/uHiK@wtujjZ36pqL/arsHNeWkTCeRRREbSqLrVtgMkRpXLRWLTxRD3uwPxiJ3cpuuvD8ILtTrfjPENdXzKLh4eS4//F44WpdaNdqOjnGG2eGsmRedEewtOM0jbWOh3LTYbRJuEYrKntKe9gJ73ot@q9PuUFkHe99BJ4yMp53qdmgESd4aZ3NPlCRkdGTTIc7UCgusa6oeUHnc3RCYQOyvQGKUkBSQLV9pwsX/@24KHtb23xwohOrY3Nvdqh/W93YP1PbePv18@6G@@4roWT843K9vHOETF3yzt1Xfrm9W@YUgUPQVYmj8chmN7kTBR3GmSvMTbr79AQ1//Ct96g0NXl0H7EAaqYXLHqRPJ@h2fgtbC2vOZQT1BU6rfFWgcvPV/VfvaM1X4a@44TRXwWx/kDmKOMvofFE959ZosqzTfFvT05WWvXzJ5fuIi7FCoqFwjWNr5PjZUwY4G/G0OqHKbMJGBWffEoKD57IBTQ09INgAZQxWKooThC0seM8Z5Dq11uz2ES9VWhMjQv0DVV8aU5M1hymmbWUAFI4f9R7Og0pr8Qvie3qxpJsdDaWAehy/kALqibyAKlqH7Yha1iUuR3uXEM9qRV78cjHY5mth9TR@sRHwLnZV4yTjxkMaqDjBIgKSdDkNnJzycKpaTinPVSIujxRp3a5MjFCSc5JMlKtEtm2jkhkSNm1cNWizN8l5ja/EDbATCtqjSOUqrq8OYRwU9jqSgO@sG/TEBCox3WHeU6uI/VTR/umdOHEdu9IM@syASJqZxiOut6W1wvC@9ajmxlSLgbaR5OSxxgTtWwhsTCHwR8AQoHxqp9PklYp9egGm39asnIv6xJE4t/3dLk/s3LpshqkK2mor90vnt99cTWQvtU8ydoqMHQ3Rb@GQ1Eq@ymz3hzTHWaxyqi9IweZ5fzDqyBjm0j3gGyde5qg0FjZq7efKeqo10GGyxV6/ZzV6Slx8S6unxJT3aZU5Xu7OY/GV5IAmzqdFWOzugE5w2r8KrbszD5dI1yGOX0gR5rtyHH6OR4yJ6J9OIjt@V0gdu1pZ39r4mP/9Zw/5Y0UsSPpmY3SI/4gx0RZND77nY4PFIfQuPdNM3r/o8hS1tQ2elpaY5QYY7QPPO7Sve9lYi7@JufH0e7gZTb7nl1@@VKRWHpJJ5/yOznOJdPPUsWnS4zonSpuAWLKTkCVZnzNvPIYZy@uXcC3CKCCYUQ9yBPv2iax6WoSY3p1etkmy6OTGerhj@K5aZ4uKJDM8XIbs8Sj8lNuoLK67hcSgRFnkzBkR7RnIJde1zFJ4vZoCt3U3OJLf9we3eid2sjx8F7StO6F9F275xdthybJkwbo/2N/vACuL2x8CS333bgcsi@Q0tJjTY@b05rOxNe3dLf48NXY89wgM1l6coMRArdYue3xFbaKP56SCa4NJFKKDw63a/r7KyP6E6pLcw5ahpcUgYD9QbxNr206PhZ0fK03xZjlWnsyblEVb4sR1@2SeSbxbRIXWQTxNj1hYJDHO250bkXp6ZWEVgq3vWSAayqWx@2xkUHSsAX@lPSAhmwya1UFnZjezsvh0ItsIXNPNE93YtuFnC2tZu5EyeDi2Adk2QcEZPEtmj9970Y/Lph1RsBABCh1ukSZN6w3tEw6o4QEV9P30CN4xLGZIYWQvCnbW0A6GX8W0hv3nGYoZSZRw0YUtsa6VY42a6MfzRs1hg0QsAwEsPfVHsWimD0bE85vn9oC6yaKXSy9BpGQiiexLmyuo@slXvYQxNeJ1shIr5PZcm2dsjg2WJzid1bDXbi/0ELbQK5PiYbIpkrZ3NpX/@zQlq0SqJUPzmZ0xHwnyyvLy42/BnuyFqZ7/s7BlDZmUn6OLAe3vE5DROOLjfeLc@q5nvicMcAfpxLTeTJiJiqTqzFhTUn3nxcjGj3CRcyFCBiH7kZd3slVX3UzgNhu6rEg2dC4y1QdrCscdlVkzRf2vdzcHgfzN9h58f3sy2VAIpoNfYZX/pj@MwsQrz4p1Y71CjID0u3A47HEx8We6AJQcuzHd6WzH3nZi8Cq9wke@b7N70tbeSWJ265mzBm6Ejxd9pOLG6d7a5PFevrRmd3W7vlNTjziEZzt1FpkZZlxL9jzo9O5CgGUwn0tg@WAfvodRmf4jHDwDksjE3nw5po37TdyYIqQ1H3NOJ20WqmVraXL021Ez6CE6ipd5GKmM9wNV5FPY2t62O@tkvbiWqk/IRYNejmp5mbyf4ar0Dge6gJQGIaOJ99aCBU8NYykJ95qzPuyjcLEV3sjpGVtOBoXSanHlmcO963kj7@L42Yn3qFnJKFp8g95FdDm8bn06659ftVVXDX45vWmOf/tVqeUn6jG1tfSDxFEurVQKHLr2Kf27qp4VmXM1gi84JjRSQ/uSM1epBZXsw9ceKJcfeNNchofEBJeqRxeGC@FiN6pcHK@cVHqV4trFce9kDU5@o8XKaLG0mMOLH2gVJRkjN/PHoxOsqfapa9i7UohWyrlZtWuIYtcQevMmGHb6O9XdV6nTOCgAOALTtt58oC5puOdgzQbfE78XXuf0MZmnwLEOFCRnjr2CSggBwOfJOI5pdQgzGhWPtNnohv8du85c0b8cjPr8xcSmBGupL50vzpxxYyryiQIVOe6YCJbwLyA4SZkcLobk7VisqPMlUddK8J10LRDHqMniMPMxk4FPIRDVvlzHJ07kh0HzHEgg7/wXrqaeP@cs9MRqkc@neDDlCIbsMFE8wSMuQOjPgG8b0ARr7hG7fTjUffwu4UHe8BnViP1k2EDeYU0RX2D@rT6zfxPXf04EEMLPic7l6yNOrXmRIim@g3y4gMBv6Y0/rhngVimDMofOAra0V0mAs6U40wjNajLR@7lrkFNoRf/TPciX@NdUN@LyrhRnkvA9tf4VgZY8pPxpHX@6SbWcVS1vqpnCFinmvkkNnHTR9uhNSNNqrDbDbpeQFlrMJeTAI/v36vYX4/ajY7R5EiMv3/NT3/Op7758F6SSUj4t8Emhsl0ok/2clPuqMkkxb6qtimLlxaeRbvqkkiRl1@4qG/mjfqOTFF6Ph1K4Mv7wPPUhb335acboy5cHqToxg8ffj@W75u8lPfIxlqmyL9Pt46@jByhk41ltazLBpX6v033h6JTl@gvYLEPUVEqqcypKZSZVRftganFCGhzO@XnarlcSKIslI3F4zmTWn7/M@FrJeJGbREO8GKcm1ow5YlGJ21xkwt2wwyK1w58fWCAYJhhNmZm7biqPdeWxBRalHphmxQtyaoJT1yaneAV@kV/wj5nsaeRMuezsj3OC@Y10Xryb0wRiofsgM5tMaWkCdxF5qTt1xyqStD2ehDhbSOxap8Bxm6H4YLdxDP4glhO2oDCSYoru8RdN6aRAybDvbUOIj1@dvxUeOa8C0rEH3fBGVbHNCNgLy0k5uI/CaBQhPhaH7okuB4Mubh1Z4btmF2qdGmBpGdctCURrZfedOix7pLyHJ@2QTpV8tQfI1zAQST5El2dncCaDB2z/GqIVJy6dke9Ue2M50KA583hJ3MxDheAbLIC7nTMbCRk5mT2gdDQImqHvkI4WkfbjSFfbHZ3Alc/T4TeCMGy0pJUd558uO81Pm69wn/u0VHxcskh2pa@Di/7jJ4mDFRHJfFhCJMXl0hPHse6Gm3I3nAdAT@1goX9HvBlehb1e6FRpxeCCESmtUTi8Clu@4@yH8SUw4IKVcTMJP@z@5bAphzukdAXEjPASjjy5DiMOw1@sz3Jd3OS7Ms/BpVVy20xDfdVpgYDG46Tdx@0wX1ggTIDQA5UuwhER5ZGr0ijx3bPGhXWXCxxEETUQ58S6m4jJ0OuPOk0aGT7JcroESq5BksZ6rQlMqL1mN4BzsD8LAbjHJBQwCJirpLtwcPSl@XfhoHTHzB17YEamQNKvz3OFpns47JD0TQjMo8LVLNxpgA9f1w/Uwd724fvqfk3R89v9vXf1rdqW2vjAd9y4KOeoxOr13g5Jl/g2XW7N9@hFpnpANTP8wanuflC1H9/u1w4O1N6@qr95u1MnaAR@v7p7WK8deKq@u7lztMW37wRB7e4dqp36m/ohFTvc87hVU81J6qm9bfWmtr/5mn5WN@o79cMP3OJ2/XAXjeFWv6reVvcP65tHO9V99fZo/@3eQU2hY85W/WBzp1p/U9vyqX1qU9Xe1XYP1cHr6s7OREf33u/W9hUbCVi93KgRltUN2sKiJe7nVn2/tnmIDiVPm0Q8QnDHUwdva5t1PNR@rFF3qvsfPA30oPZPR1SIPqqt6pvqK@qck/sGVWhcNo/2a4igBEocHG0cHNYPjw5r6tXe3hbT@qC2/66@WTtYU87O3gET7Oig5imkl@SmCQZRi77T88bRQZ3pVt89pDXj6C3sHVwa5PdEGMKySlW3mMAwg0BviUh7@x8AFXTgAfDU@9c1er8PmjK1qqACLCo2D@1i1CAR8dDuptqtvdqpv6rtbtbweQ9g3tcPai4NWP0ABeowyPhArEONHnGvMU6ElzwSszqGcz0eTlXfVtWtd3VgrksTBxzUNbcw2TZfa5r7iFlsHaJ0@jgzCC7sg5X29KurEFE6p09kZp/RxBGTNve2arQi62BXmeTDEa06qxOhlOxvtNLEH@lnKmRNKzy9PGt0eu0@fEzjanLwcRGdeUia5CLjzEfnjtxh@nyFK2Szjca7aoM2ugeNhuvdp2YKjW/V0Mfgd5VydR@RkQI7bxz8lMtC9@cpQq3/oC862VAPFxAoKdT/QUzfgovQVYVCK9TV4LwPwOboKJJrk3NcpZBoZGdHpMpJmuSTCf7d0ezAFXMGvN9s4JwUlpFcqB/RP70vyQ9ZHKwXJJ3luKtQwCaW0ej8FppmpBEOicD/6IgEnTY36Udh@OksV7Sbw57fP@v3WznXNXW47Ij2gWc59xvVT8Ozier5yfqMLF8762QOkdl3swoT3z9rkik9Lv6Qe5bDP40R/3ENNhLzAaem3BQfVutDy9wPUh0WSZ7SoS3gXsGDDJ3vTfXH@nvs5opLT9Ym3r@O38vcgr0g4vnSgnfM9U74z@sTKUATjGNxEEk6OkJGoWDVMfYmceFrKniOQtedFix/aK0@D3ldJ5KQInsZdO02sRoPOzc29iSHX@1X32wcbW@T6AS2T1aXn66sOXHYrR89@fsB7XDIXY46NqB1nPQ0/mTNkk1SfHimWBHPE/ZnBi4UUBDR7M2g8UvEeYjtNtKWTBBk6G6EvFE9mOhlQtAhozgAxwPH8OvMmakZIJfqqoveXAQ3rOIHpCsxD2hjlu6YR@0G/wB2PP3NFI87pBlIsxgHISbOpd0Fy73MtjEV5c0NB@5BET9j@FjCuMU04KMutp@Fdy3/0rxtjWIkpoyYrzzsXJOQeDCJhTJ2FT2Z2W85zog@AOboYfTmR81v9PhBB7jjcHdBNKqODoiM23FNnFMnh9G608ca8gmyiyCommnpucIpv6uR4rmnj5PjwCDWbGBUkCoHNr5pwGtxHJHJJtkC9uWCqz4LpyJ4B@CsaY7Vv4lzZ3VHQ1kz8UP0bxOVQgmsOMiJUO06bsMxRT7EcSwMOVNk@lP0YPj/QJrMgP@cdpwEPaGWFQTwXpRkqEIr2r4yUTrX5qLBut1IqGm/@pCA@WoPzHncMX17cyP@NUQCPTpj8@IDhz1s52YQAEyOgw17/sYmaecBbZ1eZlxdHfckvebFIKf0WmGWiim4@ZUTj9Uuz9yt4IerXDlrshrcoarqpWzcTnnW05ZpYiuvHkYZAeea@B@FR3wAEk945tJzsVqd5KyinmVGDuhQS9aC04ojJpFa@vXWW7tHygqRmZL9@ubLEIpArwOf6X5ympW@EvPcdMRFXonVIUfBQ2B1bJOx@OiQdadsiNkNAedhiw9DkIlldI0FoivQOVRfAk3lHrKhCBpJrA6TOIMQt65PpOVl9TrGnk8mwaEx9kc9iekfyqmWKeFLgA@Noe0u76s3wZhQ7t6v28JihUcHfQ@2i2hMjiV0fWSdafb7Q1IdA/SbcPQ6Y9dX7/WhQ9iLLoc6fiGtZ52hPpEwSj81A7VJdu@8zEgwfUYt6ozgrdDymT@4SxchLEQlPMlNfkXliHkNj66bQ8fOzWJJ5Z4nX54TTTgsKRPxuVpRX75IKSGoDhkaMgU7Uby5YJtNbgf3DvH0u@4PP2HthwrUa4WtODKpBZLPAmWQ6j2O8dgcSdcH/YhPNGgocAISU6IkB2mxoSqt0U81O2m7pkwSHROxS7kn399OzKTGWooaShhXt07Mt5KnwQSVlnRo0DhYaGlpmVGZteH6eutmjKOFpq@tVeZjLxYpZVEiKg@N6ognkZvx0wc86UP@ysMIs4fe4I5bq6BAGDor7lWn5RzjB5uC951w2LLPREmTaQUDHL/x1qffY140R4c67F8zGEXhmHYAzULnpsAwGrm/9M97jc1@Nzjr9DsB7dMQCf9GJB4ex/yIATsb9q8jTqjEH1pWodY4eZb4MhKGDb/je8k1KzRXNAoHOdtMYTQcV88lTASfnMMIMEnmyvw9mIyRFtd5spxUctL@p2yPV3LXbq37uDSrstzoA4AWcOsTFhTiQzpixyTL@XRtqsDpXQUsHE9VXgXuLRZ7KYyfEYn4GiaFsUFmyizB7gR2ZrdifNy68Vocg3CIQEvhVojUQFGOX3sB8mOTFHkBS4GyKq0Wrapyi3KDOIR4GN9O7qWn/2DsCYE/gX7p8SxumcUILOLaJtpSJPsVHWWUcGHzwA7LaJbEJMU6Z52e5X7IeThuJqGmP49vowZb/pBSpMPsTXElZmSONj7I@5drkMhpjF0sKgtqweW4HVBBqqNc8XaGDb9lP8uTH5e4cnIGwbSpIecspG8jVZOohAzEE@a1NsoSU/nbM2Zp6b6jNkHAyiyTMysTdi5jNBf2QOnI@oprrf6QhHFmgnra1GMhGvUHC/ek3q2yY2Zktlm0brruNw2BhdkqtFg@ajFpK2M8jtecSXwmmCZNMbY0Ix7C9pWfYzafJOJNpYH5VmmMv0GH22iW2E3Fi0o83i2Z@1gUr2DRaxaaeEox7ghSuha/P25Qxxu3SxANU7ZXDZYYDYiMxlgeLVATZIqpdH8KMfdp3Cfo0SLKod0W0c4en1uJOmkkZ0Kemk@pIJegJwK3w2mT5NKgDeMLhIkTDTcWUrHCeeON@SqvlD9FkGF8EIDQisN8cg4lJ7jJYE3wEWcHaOcasBYqQRLR07pt4RAH/Y8JxlH59eGOtnhojPOlkzWBdBNDol0Fl7oLkvE3p5/HjRuGMkUKmuIzSBH3aEo2nd@/V3@2L1SOIEht/qwtfYseOuOqRcKG/rE/NW6gAydN6ZqpGZWeCA0WDTQXaJdy1g1luwrtrzMUjod1g55GtIGQ1zn8WdQ1EM57pRhTG1VuWmMUcTW5Zba5Kr8uVRKGkt8gv56KouryxpUAhIIx1a@UCALCmjL2uBTg0Ds256UQ1WNEFSslTEt6yVFREzvPGd9BVF3gybJVojirxDMbRn4mEFIsZpdJECGdZXaRBAotdDNxsUo8nd2fpAQpxIb3heI0FHpU0jSMR04IyKm3i24iUY5LyitqDuaPT5bd1MeYv/nrs6L1tTj5legTY3icL01@XS2mvqaaXVpKV03VJHq4dqupj0QK10Y4lgp/7n/smmKHPI9tQq1NRkrL0PbZSI1Ou0zat/m/ROo5O2UbHcPAsz3DzfarISlWUkHZ7w7Arhb4ygCx2/90b41lqsFE5wrguHTG2SUnG0LWWDNY6tEt7HRNpL04QIHZ0/bb6t3h9nYq7Ovp2BgaXYTD5WKxCCY@tYPfG9tqHCV1@oV06UL7ststDK7/Mnx3WmDZH4acEqBsdtAhDQlNisjvD88kMwRwoKIondeOrNjrX7bbdgoG3FBi8GjYpKSOhqB4AerERi/vDvkAiEHqBfZndBD9@1nFs@86EEVTQzHXUFQbJsFXGXN7RuTBizbss@ObKgYGwWysmWjdcivrn7GCILMJDxaHL3Y/J@bJmddht9v31HukZEakgLmvkxW2t@0KRSmCG0b27r2MOB6tp8KrTtfyK0YRm9cBzixMJs@EiQuP2Pj74VntZpDLHP@UoWWFuryIbi4iPrWnMmcZVweLvwdY4UNC@16lL4JBrsl0mixMS72ewckTYfS45M3c@6SKuHwmpmn27dIg6mx0fQ7WQF13WRcwsex5eLkntxSPiZv5eFNqg4ZFgaFxQsyV@9WAq9k/Tixejdrt@0lFTgMgA/tdElEyofw5gch3ADwD9fQjeiKK9l/zNK23JwKKiIKDZB3TcgcVGqjgOA@blV@vc9VqVc0PFhdVtbpBD/m8qm5U1RZebGyoLfq9gd8/VJaWl9dE5m65n@nlhnn5VW0QDD7hXGyeD7foJ32rwG8M1toY4vlCZd5bm29Unq@vRYXj6gbc@unpP//lf/7nv/6vQlX/@Hf82OAfxz/FhXzfL8w3P8//8HUNv4@3ThbmT4/nBycLZ2vgsr9x1PB@fZQPEvNRf3jqZGUVsN6yHanZZ3P0GV1VmeSBF8HwE0mXsso2o0JWv40kcxTL2GwztN6H8KM8pS28STowuZUnJLIEdIzjeBqdZggDPFpviJKEC@xApb7crZiDe4SDiQvEtypZHYmHddarED4tSSQF@OLSipXv9KKwhxPwK9Z5pXuOE9Dfzqih@bfw05vobKN/ox59zKlHRfXIU48yGf5TWnlGb935QgfeuVKMtgOZjEdfkqsFmBmqqMOKHu8fONfOBLkdZ55T9gCSCVPBhcULzot3f@wsIwnXojNnDtlIlRyR8CUTqmQ/z/e@0rB8phJfMylXG1YUGnoXw41ZNyrx@EIFCiIxBEhavhCClPvUJG762CMZTwXzRo@1w9mEGDDIuv9qm@c9XtBaNN/TNs@pvRTSHLH5vLzF2rgmztCMNr5I@wkCfKEi28kiexIuZBccsfK2esndFC9su3@a@cTWYRyOjG26VPpdWUwg1tw24eZ72q9FG3LL9YrKdOLrFaupzKTtt3KsKheX3VFnoN0VuHVMqM9xa19lJmFEGZDAkZj95ekZxgcFJlLUxLBIsqyxavXRdZkJPe2aTgPs@nJzZBGh8FOO5vaXibntFthLxLCD8AAjFZvytYNON9JRV4ZM7LNgeIrsgEGbE6qN5N6Mz/OQVXYC4347RtpnyGxynsxn6kp2MAzOLgJPZXf7h8NgXKdlizSfUdN3qYcIwQQkMPl007O6ZxCWHukhYYrEXWHLISQv6I51ejQZ20zsc4IhNVNBh13BJEixE1My/JIaqwk6Jlz9HYNgozwlvOPbSC1iWfLC0khDythuMzzNpqaOY1qw5048cTKOoBrPTMMLutIlFtoLvvglSd5FjADddkZ7AWpXhJVnaB@r01nYC1KL06DrGEf/wpqSdRHzmVNRijWSo6E8LSUZ74AV6ZE/paNAyNpkwhk5c7nc3MdIp3PL2usIB/mObfELgerECeg4gRl7hqijXkeE5cQKleTA8FWdLf8JQrsbnBF@4@tgDFb8mM29eFBwj3/62Dt5lPvY@/LxN5cx0SLZrLJ5ldWX2UZi6blCK2PBS/00VmmRCTX4sZcu8LGnxIfFIgEhUsgd/1Q4@VIghD5mXfdR4WNWCJIaMmBSuLu9AsAXptDMprEoZJ0595FrBj/3ouQqWlv5L8ZQXrjyl7Awm0o@pqd9zrBNoNhP99dLcTmJCqtLxSdLpSe0EzoLb/LD8BLrbT66PA1vSJWIsJ2lpefjbyluSBHi600UrNHLG@qnpDUR35NIOylpEaqnObfjxGxFdXzhCSpPVOZwqXBxceMyAS4fseH3FLGcKcuxoMR00OK@HNbPqH@BdoIIcm3SO0Q4ElYGYiPCR6h5QDbJV27jUNdMlwX2c/LVJmK3MhAa3kLWWi16/V5eK2uuv7AGJRpeM93V4mpxco5OTdHUDJ3XytTCA1Vaf/H0P/5t79fsKLu@VHg/pL@j7K/ZldWsPNID/Xpsfl1l17PPUWzla3ZcoD0wPT79j/9N9df/QnDwZfyc/llfNrBWxtn1fIWrfMmur9BDaWmJ2v0///zP1Id52bEhF@t8w1OM2JqhyGbQY96l76qOXsq2dCERK@yYBRhiYUh7c/oBw6ibpdUiH9NltVXFVagjXxl7FL3Es2HWiE2F5CTD2FOQZiQVKmggLyCNCUVbWbYbxmwDzJugqX5@6K9EtAP4WZtzxE3GphsPI5gMzcu2iAYwJy3Sfl4e1osvMrF5RzljbErWjAqJrZ2WtauP14gd3vbDUaeZtpIw0/WiGVyHpz740A9bl7Sn6kXd/i/DwhWx5EVpabXQxuF@ge24CwOGlB@M/d9IEdTJgGhjyEannhrSCPQvEMLL42xBpNBvx3dSJp8kadmDsClnWOmcxFREfPw8uR5Gd/xElc7xv6TAI3OmTgRp5Ur72KOae/tllVmMC0o53vO6wOYtG8fqEBh5sYYdsGzyHe4DTgdNf/zq8IydkLgWoq5LET9otRqB/pZz5jImVZrnzJ2H3UEl05bw7oidihsTTX9RM2@Fku/gBCGfZ0EHWBfhKKAteiXDb7AfT1pAmBR91xqHikvI2tZl9a6@VeGsK3c0fS1NX9OIQktI2ol5xorGpuxiIlsqOKochg1cqc1smFqLTNLmoc9/gEEkw1Jvwy1Bd4c9IIlqSXe0VZk9bB7vhYlHrkPx2ZOjRclc7WQT50fPlBAPauhOaNeXxkhAIApuGRbK9PtAPCAqJs1op@dIPL@Jzya@hwbDfdhDKFE7bJ0EH5VlqXeF3DedEftSKiKBjitr22A7snrEoOMQW3EK2gwOXjIuWKpd5s0WFzTDUeY00CYkVCYj51THTRWnl23r7LWSKIJeZIqlpcdPlleerj5DlrM53dvZYFDJxy5gcB4QDNaoc7TJxvtKJbOQkVdIQT3dJKDPAosLOJh1XbuuCft87T6olIoaWDHDsK45jYZU18eVDDKBOAx9rAi0R8kNM7nci/IxOnbyseV@of@Iv018QGY4E442ENJb4/A2iUzlXEjAgQoLZg6Kk3uMCCqu/mKXDfvtfUSbCGHrKmxPDe0gAsTofNi/PDu3ucPXoa0OacIQwTkuNXZQr8JREmDMwgq6qD5wqFveFxUD73i6BzDKxZIAnU@A0zTTcSsDbWmK2bFAixAia8JjFVeIlumozc7Mnb2@qu1uTSKWtdPQMVzftmwl5Y4jmSGADHL1Wt09JOrqaBfsSqplkpeKqswCrohyJXaHD@Ar3UQiaosqRlaz3jDK3UWWEvNiEto0qUrjCLxmwCwVv01K49dqegGCGEGoT5NiIebF9zk2yRKc7EHGPAUvZ8qWjeibThRxgDndWMbVFqVciLMKzDm3AMS5TTEjHSmWMaL8WOPEyzLaSOYoXtE4GtBmyPFONZxZktNMsNVtJAGwkXXc0AL9r@9uemqrRv9sv9/yoChvVP@Kfscpnm/Ht6TxLZVVfdsMgR0tlm1uYTP1K1yUiFmKOmBsgiCEb1uyIoZJ1IBafVvTXib1cWpunyRcAXYNtBJuTkf1JEGgFz4DmdOb9zgUB7vr8LuyHF5NS5o4pIqeFnLEdffEtmgyl7QaQxJS3gPE0iSIOFBLwu1zCcOLBTpr3oHeuxjGrm/P5ukUy8qGitT27QKRPc2zt1LmLrZY0myxVMY43sUXzLd38sZp2O5rX7SYOb7BGw/@GG/k788c@f8WzFH7x3DHY80dj8uQPcIdcdhw9ujkNOz9GRxzOuY1uNHqnHVwPtS2fqITRc8CwAIPGMKHlD6WiujbLeJE5WZ/WJxcj2AktLQMx4A/1PknuvNPypC5/LgV/lftfP7v3Pll3fnlMtaaGSOvVTsr3Prfp8eJSphLv5g5vFB3pZj7R3u6onu6UsZqOmOY/7/3NP//qKdPdU@flhExQS4cJHz93dwsmkj1YLNeT8wtfEcH7cohj/1srnSx92pVMrR5aHcvo/MKtHX1h/Ff1fivQhrxE9LQ4S4itg2N9/KyPRVnedEs@ZRDwclKeiL9NZHRrf7qBSvZj@gFSoQ0H2wN9UaFFHJPPia3TX6iPybSN1587ouzyHadLBMX59YGWnaEJTeZ4qL56iSZSyvxurLFMZDV5uH@zuL/EDJcBJ@0Fxohj6G9Drtds5LYW7DDOOqU7ozVHcA@0HuOFKtocjKyI@3tHbPL3O1SjQNbTKyLszcJctWG@z/aS11A37CycuPIiGjj6/pmVwXTXLO9kDfUdyk0u8u6x3@IS59pLn1WVvt6Y3AbqQJ94Kd5MdmnLS0v37UGSC0ffzABix6Vv2NW/V8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/pftlc)

Command line: `jqbef98 polyglot`.

Language::Befunge implements `MODU` fingerprint, FBBI doesn't (`(` reflects):

```
"UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@
```

Of all fingerprints supported by Language::Befunge only `MODU` doesn't break Pyth and Trigger. It breaks LMBM though, but it is easily
fixable by adding a space before `"UDOM"`.

Answer (score 1):

## 375. Befunge-98 ([mycon](https://github.com/jgriebler/mycon)), 16378 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#8""C""Hata>;re^;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$                        @,,,"375"< >"863",,,@9
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $p/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@   @,,,"364"<      >"473",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<      @,,,"369";@,,,"372_"^ s;k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@_   ^_^#+1y2^;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7apSdUl17/UlWSyQBEmUQIAFkBJZkiq6e3Z73bZn1tPTnmi3Pb7tnvVsez0R453YWbd37JkIez9OOOaTf0D5sbHh2HD/g95zTgIgKJFSVXscMbGxkAgk8nHy5MnMk@fk46Cje8Of/SyGF3vqWPOB5UzYxPAmrOeap4Yrs3tzdlc3vbyWFQSMtesOpiPDnngVIcZUxizdHkz1gcH6pjUx3DTzDIN1DMs5g3CNse2pPfWMXh3esozZxhk7sLtmDyCwiXNi2OYbw4WwHGP3DetidDFhXWc00u2ex8auaU8oNM/YUx1e@tPuCdM73sTVuxPTsSGowNhz29JHnZ7OKPrYNXiiIgNQ3RNKsxxSYuyx43oG5OB0Dc9z0LMMnrprOo92n3x8Jb6aYR/rgNTYMmZXsldV9plpuL2rKTT26fGDB1d9s@xrkmOzB9dRUnNsdzpxDiZX4efZ7sCwdabJZVm7GlgAYk4Mq5QpZa4GFaE@jYnZXcoHAh6YLtSu7tci6@o21BbW5RYzRuPJnEm8/nXLCuvWY7rHpt5UtyiePR11DDeI6E10d2LaA3ZmToZsMjS9MB3F9sZ615B6hmWOzInRY5YJiZy@DwVA2z12YszPHBeq3Ifp2NYcEhpds29ikgAPAIhXYjI0OJyRPodKtifQOJjOPEDDMgJoSSEG8e8bnemAOdPJeDphgFvP9PSOBUA7c9Yz@vrUmqRZB8KAyOR/NjRsvzEDOBlAHDscq1dTQs1YtHm912MZaMeAx4nBTKAaoVVh2Sz4M8cFqkGsACMfGLVrXkZjBnUGVdR3KiyfyUD4fuiD2OqW5/jILKOGgTb0VaozhPvUdQauPgJq9Ayi6acHT5nXdVx4gx/G5f3pJjBdfcK2t1l8/8n9OKuH1SK7HSGsoho7hyqIBYHsVLem0EKiNeFA/bhhagGrLL4Rr7A4kEXLsFyO5aDblpiWByKpmTI4oP9rWRV@BaaVWE6FHpSPpzGfvqsPTMvgUAYIpYgNX8szDe6ZHMuqJR5z4Fh9Hq1LmRVZtsQKRVbMsyLcy6ysQW4IOsfUch5@BfgBtDKgosIvm@OAFu0e2im2tT3W10emNfehE/guy6usCBABXxUgayWAAM9sFn9Z@BFay1cU9mQI1B7qpwBesswT5EZGyJCwChV4KFtbCnFEZLk8e2@I2QPpgGj5EitC9gWgRA5QAMpqJcg@n@EF8YaGZfnJhh4mI2yLGfgB5kWgQwmonwFaZpCYRfjBO/A7DRibBlxMA8akATPRNHBnMQuIV4CwAlRlwafXUPdOICOej9Yj4gNHBzAqUhuZmIpEAghQWywLdVZgOWgIWWwI@SwD/AGXYoEBHyuprJRjpSIDepYzDOpGBbywlajAP1XAR0VgUP8qNAAVcFKB2ioAVbN5JkSIrWYxHNJmIS2QRs1Bmhy4oeLUAv4gHbQMFbJUIU9NKy8aIeCm5aG8@Sy1Tq0AtVuEMKCbBrhq0Jw0wFYrQTimLQENS9h4i/E0J4SOdIBaweYO7RCIkQd8CC7EBbdWzHL66dZ4qHeQW/OUnT4mLWA3KCAZIWkGiwfPHFITUMkAGOwFgL4GLSAL5MhC1WZzYfaWCkAaCN7omcSgLRN4lxpSqJimBvlKH08WZFMLhNF4PhmGfhr3c4BxmsD8jIHenYeB0PvSYeDCt5BFX4147QJQJoe@HnBWZ@pZCyChI6dRVsapaS38SuTXM/Re3/SGbxe45iiTjqFPbPNkkUs@n44QVY8EFDBgyauYjcadmBIMV4MhuhZl0YoYZ@yEFbSEsqoSeh2jP7UHhlQuRfCjkMnUncDAssizzL1dczCAMXkBR01TMWmgXHjnCUMrm50IoSdSF/N0TRi@77DuEASKMLDM4ZfLCxhZDWHM9Q6O6hJIYTAKlHHc6psz1rnTpVFjgWCW6NQdmuMgcmVt5EjlUiazUiHSNohyb0qZkDXj1ZJfOaadiLN4UrgUYKzhkmV0pIYB7TMcpXDcxaYL46pDUsOCfSbsYGRMAtGWB3kYdS1go1ApXR1HYByPDBpPAzjmRGaQCYiBhnOKYisNikvZeDRwdlyUUkHK6RmuyzAuiLZemoZYb9rxjNdTlKMWePVhzDZgaO/rphUiQOOIPiEBAJ5xD/KbL6Pdd50RDTYjHEItxxmvEVdgwD5DQA@dM2OB@mI818djC6Qm8De40AbInOkkb5NwHs2VIwSJMB1UOACkrEDaMF2jS7T3iw6psyCXLKNYYVr9Thah3IuIU1noLCBqeJjGnlpWBeQco8uydaVnnCrow0WuZVELcQiEMBClfBAdHWRlxJywCCHd0WQS746DmvWc0XLR@Ph6EBZ9aKJgZJ3pc6i9PgytxkwfgUTPUGyGnstG0GJ4DWJNgM6CxTpgPceOT0IoZy4IsVDosCQkKCNNJubIAO3HgSRY4zlCGkd3wqwzh6ZM1MrJpO5wTK4QShauEop75CIevLOAuNebdpFqmLdpUwsCMclDGd8FVsn9hInLmk0dfi7Ic2Nfw5PRgRGPELWIguDx3u5L3l2CiDKqYXugVngyM1H/gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDswLEi6gN0lIiAJQq@Z3JUFIjk2oNGJxUzWHY8Z@MOgBM3zQaYEIqjzymRvINAaggrRnbrunM3GUBPmCGJNuk6/D633jTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jBdMfLxVy8bRoQx0alZO/pL7KBAWQHgbWP2ik2@UUBxmMqApFCt7kwa@tAKSxCdzwnsgixRYq@48jo33MMjxqL456EXR8z84wBdQ3oZ/0FMxqhcA6t1Calogecx@9eCB8zFFYWBrPyW8HHhg1dpwutEjo9VB/W6S7rg5IdEWFRz9C7XWM88duJQ@zMtCPy/uEDlPfJV/KByd5Q2LzLtq@0GogatpyILIv6D6I@9tUQHXmtr8lLJHiEKifnLNb8WvYQ4/RK7uJLjLOEwUtxDQ5j6hKo/BCTmE6QlSB3NLtD5IUT5DYkb0Nvc6fXiw9@0ezdEZP6Yd6IjQpsR5CV0AvxWA9Dgp91HZA8thBWfckDoy553AJa90YrIDshklYv6isrugxM8TagI8d2VkAFYoZwMcpyCNUFNcYj5Bq6FTZG6i7eUh0hw15MLuFABmPoeOy40DM405nTTAJVWaR1@Qp4IhwrkjK7tzy0wpARxwF/gqMgJBhbOrQF7GLYU0Gz0oFTABPjCjLwPIfnGEGYej3B8vE7I9bPGxOMpbZtoHKmu3MOBIoHwzNkNGem6wIbPMVBgo9BwWAiUzuFMUHv9ZCzIjmo31/NXMYWvTftmLOrWngXPeVXnnCqu6yPCrgLQgd0okS878WTVfKnlJEgUXHGE4WS8rsIESmSDFWe6INOD4PEA2A0R3O7mxCXupiYZuJ00i@JSXBgQi6jsU9AVbiKHaoP2GhGJ9Cv6a3KBjB8SxLcJfQjTDBAkTFAd0HOgE4IWma53Ovo7AK4h8uk2R5XRQKVRJVzYV6G3Qvz8gmBuETLK/MsPLdLDikyqmEJMDqVnAaJJQK@JyUooQgeiuKPrehB0h4PI7mGe05tmodjCS6KJNl5KPzCAJAgZEwQPsyuOWn74sqdO4HgslGrQWMDaQrYZi8Z1WiDCUsZODVElkka8TORJ87RBPtGIgnlxciXHBsQm6Cl1ursfDJ0ocfR@6UAkYCsgo0tOSCsX89PzJNp72pF2@iJkUTsdSA0md2JWBVg8Oe9oXYTVeNLVAWtN45UxcaL6Qn0tcZLvlihoh/NNTwUf2s@KpEaTiAGfltdSSKe1PdbNOi9edfyRQLugs7OuVEH0D/xJ7JCRpT2ZYKg017rqRwIdgcOhz3dPX5Y8/siD1Q6pl1Z8rCcrm6R9yZGF4O0jw7uPdt99ovtFTAss1O56qGYuVIBh9rpTBrYUyUna5XNKIwF4Pvtm2FjwuU4ouAHM8mZRUSleRcGl1lAzsNnX7tKEpCEkByUA7jxd0Wk4XFA6BI6uje8MgizQSoFWYZJgrhMOmABzNCBqGO4HuDzdPrmDVbeVaTGvj9iZk11DiDwVA7sIJ2MgVcEsCCo0@cjIqUFKdS0caFh4YrGDPD5GKXmq8iQKB1pMh8fPth/ViOw/ryaRFEUbwKylO72ZGjz1hRU8FVxgP2Bq8tS8gJxlKcJ15UE7naXCLyoW7YGPgBAXUd2mGSNgqJ5Q8B972rZyFfqhi2A3gnCVbkyKg91PxTRCB44xHVR5V01ilLAYrAKvVaOWGHo8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izx7UaC0KADjQCA3uhB04knoIy@kSF@s9tE/enQNcY@ESFAFpAAzz2Iy5eVZAmovksninrIHGppjGfJnxPFEJiYVJR6sC8hdj5TPSPz9mTlJZJL8qSYhLuS@u3ug3Q8i@1PWNJNBSgPq4jgyuX1c3@t60EZsx3IGDtuCNFw6DDIEsWltMXcHjn2thnT0xKLGcIkQ@C9O3OhjGGvMN6Q4UqqousoXG3XbOwMurRaySCSiEIFSKL78Sj/VgVyLch8dfLEPg4iaz2RCd4YuIEEkDZELXd2IL3kwCTKSfXxWFjBcLrzW24MAKbJeh4X2GV2YcHcRvNKTOKasrIy/EqVPnGsUf@XMrzQt8OFNCxwRkh08efro4Mn@493PmxMtn196z2XKBSAc5NcBWUgecrphb93iXROLheBi0Ddc7F7ABaagoASrRVPPBcYtYxSZI7Cm1fCF1sQnztCOe8mrhTnDUOmV3eVN6DF2Ph7VTwiKds9CZcTlq9U4nmP7GU4mY6@iKNDLh9OODEqr8qrrWPpAoXQwMFiWoqLqcnCI8xreqhSAjDc3eAo@uQWiw5xmEHVr5IDyQmveyBpYgoOnWSvLHAxBF8aFccNNymELptIoPdAQQFdWwrIRA6Y3oK3/DOpJ5E37q6pW4u1azWg5RQyiLXV/iLvRN0B1SsBoBaRIXnllzTvNO2wOXBohXQUSY/IWTXJ4DMcCi4EgSbOmqOcHxCFugfOlyCuIRq@nOJsLXErJZ3JFtZBXQC0DNQ1kVgnn3KSRPukOpYkjATzJ6dO8QaQV9r2ubvflLd8RIAty30dQ1GzjRbNpt0BAb94h3HDduTFvNdRWssquJ9ny4yer0HqXiodtN/CAtktOaJr0ZGv4WU@/zs56OvWuHlMmo7E/5khj9ngXBKk3DvDrnhHte5hAiQYqW0txFYz8VlkxIWRhUgFvSCkFOhSMtND0FMRLAqEXxUNoOcC3IgnYYjaDl4Pv74jwEVS6sd2bTtyjNRKUa3C21BsDEWmyuYtc2sP5wQmMjmHLRy4NlYtMmp0ZcZxH1z0@WwmJ/DX@ID3oaiEEmpUPZ6TtcFcDNAJKReo5cA5oVzhtOlzMMqLSDy0NMiSccPIBJAibVg8GwGcgMS/ILi8Iz4l8lot0YjtnNkLrGKwkdcwJn@x3pi6udZu9aNkgelbjcQAaFS7C12lRvGN0@SwrT0ylACVQZyNj5OBUAkhXxAoMKoLOF9RRF/Rwxhq6VUbCFUOAL7G7e8DFugafL5JGqERBk9pn8Ymr7EpfKLr0BlrzDbIVFj5SxX6lHwcEWN7eQLMk/gwoSSfOiCJ9RvMtGHgvEHcFXDGEEkMLE/WaMzbsqzof1wgTySptQ4jH@SLQeXxjYyNeidfjaXDtgGsbXTvoSoFrh1wSuTCejC5KkSYXhjYoBfq14peNAPIs2cI2MEPJ4Y05TuiNSiXbSusN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6EwmxfoZrtmA/B4p@x62naOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9mSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt53uylmpfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXz0uQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRA3MGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/cIYD@duNEI46wZSNs6gL/aq4JYe5OJRLvmGp48KdEuafiD38ngg3OLkHcpL4znn7gLHtKks7YwKxt1TqT9yJrryqQxKkxwZLuMbcUWSYCSkEA6Jiv3Y9LAL67bhTL3oTOPKCVDMHXyPh1NglsH2tDS0KnMsGN2hw@KbdwE6C9d7cCjBpSuJL4AFAHpdGX7IRFEqwcUSkC5oQ5EJfJG2YtGsjEpIcNYTzM3nC@PXcphbldKwDGZkDmzHNSQgCaQQaPcU7ckT6sG69AHNfF1bl/BDaUhDxds0gCM@sBydaMvZdWQ9aDyKpAf9HJI8M3qCBfyjD@xR5nXhGj1lS6BVWscdwggBpUFOrIW1NfIDFMcb9@TJDJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh84z1NE0rdPP9ShCGrQKIPYRKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzPp4UCHf3J4f19PndCgy0OrziP1h45vSnIlb7e9MywB2m2D@3JtJ2RCWQI0r85sZ45zoRr@fCybmaGK83maGrpNOdzdVrmxnRdp@NYNBV0U9JF/Knr6ZbOJ6GC0N1PH4Os//z4qCZXIpEU/XR0Y944D7k6W07Pg@iaI623BstDHm@Y4mZexHEr2PWJbMYPKGDA1N/zCXUU@BfRP@hSuIbi@5fQf4T7PUFW9mcR6DX09COWKSLuAcUNb77nuZq5RP@1OlgYT6V4XHBcYHuuauR/Oun3l7yz5H0iIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xChKeR4JN4YuxYkCKlCccH/o2nhFisd3t8jhyuLjcBPC0LCCpcVnILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHetfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVcIMUVExa2L9W1HCbhkeT7QIlqQqeAurETMtIzVlxv3URVzwiQ5@Jzebso4z2OegluFty844yMKq0x2kNvapBSNyXYTtzJoHEh7H4xHV3CHyGpWbLpIT6mdp9x@pJfJUMGgzj@hVWkL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2f1@BeqdL69QiR3aIhIOg@5@ziJH16wRow5J3K3tgyJy12KU@c9tDfKWVf3VfKZVDX1eee4O9xqbHdZx9/2si0OARhpOPKV4nX4izYngyCMwhKuI8cXLhTZ2JOSBKgnQgmlleVAakZLZIA@gCDZ1BlYUZ@iRD1C@NiUZa@AZpqwkDMvfkozYzkpdy39MnEsHmb48uP68nN14n8bGqU/Y6/6FBhGVqZAcnUxDBAscqOju/vP3smQ8v1EvF9XMGpQHfUu0MQUNYVOqBktPAV9lEvzj7CNElU2wXoaqB9tP300Kir0OhB/4DckXcMDDcBnklcfOmCN613UUIuofkEwv1W3QnRKASWMJJQJgJWWYn/c5urWj6eFWjxKaIkkDtxpwK0NZPy1DZfyx4MNCS3QpQ4V1ZhvKhtJoiLbapJf0PdCJeOQcMioRFK0Ggw6Q1wOYgsslaryvcAQFxUwNwBUlcUqSpoF3tNDaq@Bt4g0hAEP3ntLXvRyEjlVmpzFSjaXOZvQOflj8BFCMugPWNltpsJ6u/XOjLHga8Fcs79nNTpK6cvKmyTO0Q@50zRgw1TxHRof9XyPqnlXVjQyZCV0FQMFiRgCTH/eIDfZimcOD/oPJiMPBJJdh4SXUOSs4sLoiHb1BjREFwq45VxGWifwJgeOVCaR/7RgKh0QL3V30iCfbYpiIGatbxSiyFchFdOr0in0qkYTcelQ9M@cWi9J3S1M7KaR4kwTD06sa6nxE2odFuKGuLA42rrsPNGnT7dVkSgZQ9/QZ08aELdl4VBiNSVZ/SgufUVOS9vIlnK1t@eSiMtuJn0@paYUrlEkfudjrkuKhAB94UFzxXRgElhe9bknKwGZw1wKgbGI2BcXHtZFP3q/iO2RHd/H63//M/f6AH9r9fOEAYKnHkMHW0YurGmpP7ayvKT4gvdVlcsnyCfWqZOhCHXbSC7ugtF0q3QsRo0LcJLEgz/I1xS8Gsc2ibeQGq8oZlxzPmKYPBcncmqRTUbWGZ3Xdwr@7F4VrT8A4pdj4jAhSDToETEunglGDO@BBNRsZGN3Y5UsGmKUWPm9T6cTqb8DoLrrZVojvF3U9/0Y2byekc1FL5z/YYqd/WTac@RxieDUE4trIi7KD2tAUsgDvjLwW10ri4@LyDfCR4810VbDG3KGT1uaxWePfXGUoe08B5/o44wuiEH1@L3dVFM//Be6FhPNdOi23u2RB86NBR/N4SCe02lCNHMK2S29M4cZZDhh7eycGcBcJxaN5XKZNcsLY/H69OjJknpy@XVqWdyl9Nj1RyBwvezSnwWjQrs73C9pVZhuDJHuiVpvYhzLTNftTHhWtRwTZPS4OELOoFxYyPHAak7tXR34bqhiS/wCJYR1s1I@8PGU7PrgDgwZmpRVrVg6IgMGMQyg61xi4xwOzHdItsfzFVkDI6TSKFrNQtwuhPcMrqmTb0HQ@NbNXFDbKSRyM46SnWdM/ytFR@GoJry@@oR7c1KrN6DOUlW19JhHF87HCxNDuLk4y0N9cz0DLqtJuzJSkQnXWul/3IXCKb9otN4tzVrz7Qcjx3R/SYCDVygAr@vbtBRWpq6LdFkeNR9Aw8K9jgsKlS3Bo5VKA0UHW5ra33q9pHv@8/35XAhh1LVWzhUIP44tuo/1/L1E8U9ua2C6MCii/tbI84bhthVbMpfe1lfOlAMcOFudckeZEqUUlb4VN@ajHHJ5UyfB8@fY@hYR9pg6BjPSZwG6Q4TlEvgmLhcxP55csvdnFvv/ZjSNbDF2woRqdwTy4DBiu7XqpRpGfUDU6iZzPuzqL41NabGSkXjsPPKwGP1NygZ749Uxi/Gpj9Tj4sDeDQljPXG1wzfC2scp/HtRmaiW2bXuF2UWWZqY5C@x6g6PwXHU3RcTzGwp@OlWl3SzuxnN5NsOA66tNNbwg5DPpQPlW6RlJbkc8@g340aE9fwcINYLZ/JZHwBJrLisvRykyaVDdO@Mvl9KWPyWeS8iIurbG7EuToPIkt0C@JaFqStU@wpcrms2KZtTOZ4f09u2nEc60NqCpgqHhh2QFuVaKvtTTV2TdzxD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2vi6JdAHleabKj26JPRetSnhoucIF6SWX2@evoksMN2WCx5uxTkhvvnWWi9L@rMhqlySizf2Oi6hOh3D0vljVsjdBK8sZ2@Et8w0/MVaXNzlS7qLpfjYFaY0ngOxzB5oKUNjZNDrDVK@3kMTGf5jbaSZg791wTPD6CqzfaO7LsLYBL5g431pDTkiLE0cG/SrCe7zQz3Fwp2kvu86Dhys@q0k8sFIHxjcZstNnHIxYYG7abhat3Cunrqo8B00XUi2MMaxvklApzox5l7wXAnw8bwL9Tod3T7ddqXzd3EO9D16@7otrNeHWHvoDO2hMeT7xsO3dZ0D2uOE29i5CXXAejDErWzj8dIW9yg9Lcey3oeeyBo5o3Sc/kqc9vHwK57c@iC4/KS9/7h18k6fcN6BjrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiR6WxfVwokefl/HQ4NF6p93BulGPR8oEjx/Xvi36pYD3ZmMx/Roj62pRzdKKtGZ5dvkpj7fmkKbIh13IL9xRh3Z95T9fSu0BL6axXTMSXeIh8Z5yzYGTqc7NG9D2jdUoQRTPvz1vXRXpIzJpPvoLVsmkNedy9heatHwI3wcrKt0f/aID2uh4wZ5ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6HoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3yuvp@ZkATSylymc3uXLEuhYh7u/e2KtZEVnJBZs2N9VsbaVkpCOArlkZEDgUddlu7zPLdLFsll@W4dQtJSEUWRfyoeQ29/7Q7ODZmTeFvyX2tfSpqWVg5w9nA686wyTT9f3QETD2/ppC9rLHJmyhjFLt/3HOjJrloKHHOHZBplraty4ppK/cVGF4qmWpDsmPNrwgKqbrp1Ds8yxx@9M6q9divP3MoEufnW9kNNmvlqZ9iumZ/T5Egi6bhMRR46LO5FBBpG6uJKOM@jIzLngxRmX7QyAqUsWW0QO4q4TW1ZuE1pd/eGYKX3@xBjouNf6kTnBzZorWgU12VXbi26F/fWp7plfn0LJ1jU2tNjAlyHd6NF@fFsB77E@MLsPlyoiRNInsL/Tkz@Wmj96Xa@Ls6Hp4Y6m0HHDxBQ2Od6IsdW1QW9YEfPqvH1orGLRgfgxyJWxV82tO@M5nhabk@umaXVzQrOs/nOd6rhuE9iNSJxNR@Op5z9W40B7pqKz0KMT8vfOTAAuvQbWyoa6NVk9Ux2ZcgUpzB8UF8510vgXpuUM2BelDAOhDYQwFM5XNJx7MDw/xQ05rr2iJVLe77nsiRMdkssL9hrq1sgyybTNyc2zOZMJbs4JnlgYPnLgCQXlEd7lux8KQTpeTZFHt8v6i6PJt4zv0PKOnKnbNdAZ2huJqgV@rsZesPsYT3Q4aC/lLKqldR0Luhc4rJVdpuvY04nkTu0bR4XCjaNCBa1NRZoBS3x9//HzZLQ10G7t26TQwB7ZwrV2w8CVRmbaIIit56PLsQNd4j63k/SMtgrfkmYXjTl1iV3fd1bpO0/nMIC8t8IEzH86um90cdnw1ryfOI8d24HRaAyMcvTM4Gf@lzZ6rE6IyR7hqXagT@/WbI4I7JpBiEsb@tjoQP1aC9f7jEUc8H19oq8ZimhukPS/0HVrWzGtjuG@okm/iHudSruM0ENjRrrF@gbD@6A06Xa5SIzzcUt9ZGnFxhs7js3vxG0z8FAf38xVYCig2/svlMu4EX9pXmClfrZc1MNTvkvE6HGjFOvK6hodx@L3G/Yk2SbfE6C7puEpj9DGAfkVckwC6cu7kYcUb@QhC9UIJNlT3aNF@tWqxgKkOvuALUBD3e06uBLmO27YnRMxTHALmw739vONAx0g/Aw4lt6d@sZCb0PLGnVGdFurMERq85nRwVNBHbLmMdFn1yuTzwz5pgwiO7pCAwABu8JOXWCJp6CNJG8ftpb0qGWqmmO6Eadeu1xOm3Uk2zS6b3ScNXOIXou56aVwKLPyhJxr5qoj3YhmkRWdTrqv7EnLW9dAoLEMaTJ0QedXJjdNbwdmVlash0xHBi4yL6/CrBVdHW9IhXVWr6eHzNU1JN/WH/CS0O4flw@l3bWSJ4KH/8N7nygwCLcLucD0CLCu21fwAfmpa/uP92mBTx1v0jdnh4A3ngJYx06wWHlIAg/eM9C1ta4QUHv21OKzD4PIvqtRj9QxiawwS5JF7HpiSIZ9KpEhuNn1Ejn80Jeyi9Z7J0ZP8u0g4EqD9Cg4/xVG858rFlCjvBE3e6oKJ@yskPO3f64i7lnAGUDecibS2KOnMvaeHjw6PJbHnrpyfNod4umIa3LckmEFrZSJTEm90t3IeiffjtYzvYly70iV9h4dyBhhDb35ioYED1yZW3qsnfcMrLgq@lotCEONyWoB8eHx40epxRFNltgbus7ISEaD946O0njS5JOjlcHR1A@gd/Sd2drkB/uqmlzRfJ/btDq4jnuuyGkdpGMDtFFojA@5XZZbhauuMzZ6x/Ox8SkMnsjBvffMvrC2kE/0U3OAvZCV1xKKOiory4VcMrIzG5Rtww2f6@rzxBwjt@zSQ@GPtdtRUHLIKm52tfRw04r/VSmGZfydCB@WSM1cb61RO8KK7v19EVNVdR2dj/Q@1CvLr62s5Qir1oct5/Q9lpINX3mRQi9pAq1KMm/dR16URsC6Fbzh9LzvCc7O2m0wNwEIvQsrO/yZYc91W6K1rJvEiwqkxk1tN0b5wniPBalwh88pGitfucYXbqlniS45k7dkfOxGkuzt3Tu4LcEzn5Y3x/r4yXP2VPfQCMnNEaMYG@@B8UIyeiXhvBVawFu7nNpzAZR2I7zBeHV/rrAj3e059nx2@yIcnUHFoZ2MC4ew8I0iGZY5M1eNVV0@r/V09Taj2/Lmhzic@ZIcHDVO4wN69@1/pqqZDJkewqea4a@31EzQwVkCXfoc7dlFg44PQtbQRblFBo/kSm30kTHD7Sh8NniVUr9yfCvcMPYVk@uHk5vCSjeE5W7I71oYerKsnFFvAJi/IYzl5TD4kWOdDR15T3cNb8X@45UI3VSQ8g0FKUe4s28tnRYWffd6ER@PLviPla312Ji4ufHQ6Zi5lWXY7aORSfYYjaVfD/e3U@gubW8ZOP6RD/6@Or@zqbEyo8f6m9UBxGlOVgYBEzSGUzoScT14eYG0AzKvYQ9Mbl@R3XMm@/R2g2IWnnhevRfBHN@fjtdjDLwRP0lxlZ0vRfwMdGbnzGP38GjcQkxfofvj/rjV/utkWhZODKKZ0YfHu0HrOjxStEiOCyw@f7rkjYdHJ4dHET/XmM3WKb3SbJ0OuTJkkeuT49xSttv1F6criLX@vBGIG8CPw@daOYgzu0@OrrMEVN@Gk5EVhHyi24sZ06UK6zkTOmm4MvDpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlsV5nZXeC8p9jAgmybk7SntNlrWb7fXtcpj43NaewAxiE24WMKB@oaXjFluGGBISdZ2VOdkIfwsoXs0Hpr2bGXQaF0a2kWaeOWt7ga77Mhyztij0KrQOvagrQaunxr2Oua06rCiVM7eLIVlr4hU6@qFf73Ef6yrknvrBLUrPAM3RNzETTD9s67yIHj5VEveGv@ToyD67XH3LAfn73vmdHR7ZAKbSt0e0b2B/V0FaN4eDT/2cTJ0XPv2qEFzqlTuGe@JxMZ7xxzNu84qHPh5ZWjuUVv3Xtq3VsTP9/NT1Z4cfJAgkbCBksnlrz9Fj4ijRejEJlpE3aTj4BD34oJt@EewIUAMDnX7h87RcKJpTw08Nc6/CTOpbUI2tZqaL7Md/NxSBRS@JOWIXmSeLsirwTbP/fPUlYp6yTZqTKyIzD/RHlqb5haTAS7aeoUyMelEZZsTCNkMTmMz@vgHu2A0iQRaq5rPwJusRO1SVP3z6oDS5vnTg6f7R8e7x8@PGpnWpX@ePSiEbUNugdWMj7I9Ecrukw2EU24/newoWJAdfZgEJ5@8oFwMP3a0XLTaUtEWhRJ3MM3muW0rCh3pV6RLwE8SeW4UiiwWvDjsoMRUP741hwo/XU9GAqCKOGiR8oQ6q7DMqozHOgham7YffvXbYBSK346r4NfjMGPf5DU0xIHj9PwcPYPdfgU5Ptg9ePT82T4LEFw0mjOzNxnWynluEZ2bGYF66pu0x7HG4n6SONRVrRZ/EAfCxOU4q5ARBrJGDu0cogXUQfMNfuotltgk@EDBeFgpyn/@hnIZl3G7fhLixgOk4pAtNHlqKBsbG@wYGgm7/@zg0/1nDPHfv0/eSCIEwY7xBPif/bjHv@cRWGgKvpvnjkgqIgs3QtQKRGAaYWG9AWlOXXe8/ut59P0MspEQfrgj/PKQINB3XaDdnpFxxSuG95JkC4t/7c@3ixhkRE0o@AYArgyhjUPXY6emZ6KFBsShjyYHlxs7biYjM5sy28VPA@IHCHX6uAygPrUn3KyXb9wnBi1NDllOmm0SsvxTNGIkYnx7Axp7xwCBmXm2CeLXpMJeQUvE1ZcKt@AhSfX4tSQB6Aq5JBSyIhGv2Sj0lKarvPu1f6IMqgzcE3B/x3fPMvfg7Vf8tz64f5W7XyjY0K7bNFzgEkUI7ZD6JeCIhPRH2ke@iGhzqykLwqHpxYCvMnME1XRKVMfoPAd@l4AdL@AkGp9CpUFzgxrzraXw/Ay3lUBDqBVFwSaFSpxMZ1WMGd84esUgaiFfyKkKICmdBgDpCwYDPBHPASaTFegmwqk5rr0ExWB7e5uJOJNj1ApVXrPKpv0iK74MEd2EuMLZEJFrMEgDSRYpIKzuJ4PBJ6UmMSlyr7gaR8bVc2BUonAcvfDd9gkhsgQQi9PIQJP4M/x45gTkG9@wbwc/Nxn5us2mD0hSYUwiV1IUfDsjT5wJNB/opIvvV3E7I7hxmo@AaDHT45@UJXu62B7l6z1rcTw@@IyO39dk5AEcVDZzdTCN1q34GYI4QhAVcVXzbbxgzUnTbim8bTJopj9c0ZhtcP@yMljTZnm5d69bU01ctYWKxGJ3j2wHp6weQGFYQlO0rKIWkosi5XIri@SXyM8GioMmmy4gO2BTwDK6hvnKGXu7e/sHnxw@PbpmMZRixq9GA75f3041JTndaIWOeLRYy1Vy74Fy9Pjeg6AiFkgXItwYGL9fEvWmkixmohHk4mTT1aKtwvBq6dZj/Bm3fXAV36x2E2qU6BoeauYD8qXTBdIDOiN4NXOttIpa@fxNKC3gKRHQe/yA9zVUE8nzy0Zru960Y/HrLWFFR3gRk7ewE4Cr6W1tKtjYrxcOCxZ@7PkYP6PnRftidnVfFDezaJAO7UtMnJOFyT7fIxIQKW@QDbBIQVaCqGt73yGX0ReGJTX@MWpuyS5qpyuCcCFzE8UjoI6D71ojF1mYxfUtwg51b2iZHSGwj8YtwwYGLEOjsNy2WSIp@B9X4Rkn/C9dzyozmbYSJpLI7QhWmt1kZDaAlxSgQ6N093QK2vxTZ8yN7dOWkftG4HrmAPu9P@VTTAb7ZDqCeH16PDNo@Q44twSJgZLxEFUuSwGX8G3MzlJoxRfya6ClWb/g8qiXT8yS8tCY9cwB8PZEMg0c7SNVbbHQDi0WmuzO2nGR6mxRCzd2xY/x2H6U7B9kjHi2QEBv6LJp94xZIn4WT1ZakD/6x88@O40nxVVtiYwi@1aCe1etI4foF9WbOYk@8XtnYHp4Fbcol69zCfC7Cphb6Qu@9FUuy0NPoC831lByP5q4j8AJYkSiP9LHLDG1uYVDmdFropmw02T6Tapz66k2S6VIoYIHBciMUvbJxcfvhG7PWUKp4cc9wdeze/h4Y45ZQ5XlFrgpkyTbxC/w7YHEhTY/kwLowJCkQmBr2IRAzQCMeCeReQOHNBgOceFBdiJXBNMHyWiVw0GaUKlZ/Q6LfFFxWXIUy@WKX6HLXLHMoPVdZ4eyAmCv8blArgfq@saPgGag/spCbMHIr3O8GOUb44g89K0mATqxiMXjwJgSA1gLe8TdoYu/xL4NfQXkg0rl@fGDdimpiCy0vjRwzR6uwnGj/aGK539mCbqpshQ1XuUa3ceYDO1ctrl5JzS3@IA6jHiFpcaiZPBtBQfKsrdom6p6Y6v3E/q1ADFzOAD4p1TbATi0TRpMz60IW83sf/azGAobiU1VPWm7p6l4PlOFm1rNszz7aLMpSZuNTO3upg5a1OT1rAk6ubKVu39qDPu9g4HSFEWWZTlF2To/P48/2HpqvsizgtQztcLr2fwyW8i@nl1m1dLrk7FaaMivZy2xVEuftNjTp5@/bb9NirPT@WuxmdBie4cXoppDlT9WKbPznUI2dlIG9RPyZeyEvYHrpM/wn9xvehG3ju5OH1TYuMhizSZQXBWLoqI04i34J3X/JVxc8W/U5bq803r7NtnQ9clszkzTHHu9HvycIUiQWvKIgb58Bzg9T6CwJj1Jg8JrNOtfn0/IMzbbNQaD6b5e1/AAs3y3XZ2b0weTx198FlzP8XrzLJLsjf/J31QqIUmNFfMUlbaej@HHg//sJxuX6fOn7e0/@@ZIMTbwcYiP71w@RveRmv9oY@Oje/dyubSmadz99Iunv7i7u5u7n84/beR3clJmY/tP/2RjQ9O2NWWj5XlqK944Oflc1DI5Uf6zH8XbT59@3fPq2f/zG2/rKt6KcDtlReATcGWZCk68l@Cnooz1vlfsTQxauRqb0187FvifbzC1vlP8L987fB2bxOqa8pkLz0nsdaxQinEnOOAtG7ydxuqxbYxWuIzNlVqtBs7if/m3kL7@CcDBkPk23Or5AFZhHqtLNUpyEasXwKFqGuT7f3/jGxEMOZuokRgXXHdZAy4xV9TEnRZcW3RtC2jVUsooShDPngwnhsPU0h31Dr6Y8AIP28DPAxiTZgw/n84O7zL2rJFKpVpyW4JLfkGTRIqqak1VvQPsQPpoq1aTthi325nN5u@g7fEkTWkNHBgxjTuf/UNcsVWe1Z8b3DMhVti4@/J@vQ5lytazW/UUXX5Hoj5VLImOc1dkafYyDipIo/XyEePGhutipqSJ6XT6bpveZ0graRa2JLz4PRYLfbDLsqt@S0kgiu8b@/B4sX28/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PsPaPbT7pl9ZQsinUKXqMN1t1Lp1uti3RXPm/heh3aUqZQqJaV92UxsAQdqPWNq5uOLeD4bP@KfNlcZayYpNVyUbd3PHt/rsYV3nfvUo35@AI9MHswvBTmWqEbukGrX4sHQ6m@Qlhqn9ZaEAlFNaqiFfEviqerBVWaNu1BNolYsi626ltcO2d32jF9suOkxJwaaYSGgo49vfVG2ehiyeKtHvWL1IFl9EedD44X4CrFGQ2kZNCAEfuzuRmWjVClUNKVdX39B04y@UlTDMJ56sdNYeHHKxhYEjYVN86pfUBXhCwtaMPuQeCAZvQ/zpVrKFlSx6ru0NhOr0Ei0rKQN2mJGFcPehvP7cG3AH/3DFb7ifYN8fG@Kcv3aYBV1S8sq@Y8K@xqOr7dcUVwFGCdYt9PpvOl2QOrQ9Y7e1dWJPtVn@lyfdKadWWfSnXYZdpnlGf2sk3dKzozxBihLsWxe3YzdoUb9trHBnnEu1GKp4Gqmbr2ey3Lbd5LDwZ8kObOYEPsHuOqqprItGJ8ycAOhjJygM@OfqgosBoLWeevtVuPtFnTQemqbmGOrLvlYwkNu322lpMvLBrirVf9/ux46q3RxFxSudZlKbb@og/Txot5IAcgXPkhZYgRUbtdb2xQSZubn5gdvt0B@kVLbje2as0c/mTqIFM858YJztwWAt5eQvXs3JYPrLgCob0J/TKZSm5K0gWNjwx8rIHKrngpKhTgkQFo4P/85f6DoQS@@3L6sXza2Ly@3t@F/m@6X/hN8L7ev/dNjca2JswhvIWtpNpR6U2n6zKIF77JSRx9ZaYKjDk@I18hqpVYDHXDJrf82/@X04h76IMotGbAWYltsK4ZGKLOxLSH28t2X/wv@mu@@/H2UFxn8GRUhdo7dWtlCbbPMlU64MfuxzR7zywY3/oJX9EGPx3X0tPnNxgUpRXkpswqf80@opUJSxgG47fTbaNdCZi8h6jXex0StVBDbKXWusdi2WCgSu/uFa1c8Hv9HL7VyMc4natAww0vP8x5HsFzgCZGrWkaV1Is6//YA/0zML6y6/tEvrLuE2EWZGRWgT9djnDJCDBpSTFEkCUas@vYIt@7jWomEaulp7XPp@a6E8yj6hFbCunyOoHawXyuX63yZZ/MpdZut@1twV@F/fwPKwZp9iNvs17ojkICb/Wxea6Kl@pjUeY1/j97gHzvu4t@z1/jHjt/g37MJ/rHHHfw7fo1/ux38Ox7h373X@Pf4Df49H@Bf8yvZrFoVN8@JNCm1rF5uzkQiUTW2U29@ZeLOK5ZhN8xey/8IUzZXZslY8yvGrGuMJxXu2Y//9Lvf/Ga8VotLcfq0TU51XKYmq0B9KJEXr96NC7Ea21Q31YyV6WbUjtoBh8kyLssMM0O1B4pKW2UZg2XmmTnLjBy1By4D/jLgMjN9lhmwjJ2xISKEgmvSzkzQ1YfHAP76AMiFPxN3onbUTJdBRhYKbfRVTAQProt2U2iwOBNfGqBryqqckQtmC78l1BBfvmwqWy2tXGIyNiq53XjZjLfEpoj25bVyjnXmxkbzpQhDc0bkjQ99WMzzQIGtxpRmU@FkAgoQFS8v2@39J/fbbQWHoeZj53Dxf3g4ir7e@D86dB4fOiMH/g8PD6HrGPXU3RQw6Lt3a8Cw/cdOrF7daVaI7QesP6Zs7zTrWQndhRRwcw39Uh94LSDCs77RFOJnCdQ9zlD9qH52Vj2tkvsseAVHu7qIEETjDv8J1xkMcYE6cgbX6Rk66A2dZ581Qxd3KJ@dgddnDPSu8B8UvOjrf4V/87@t/8fPWZIlGq1k4vxyO0FXEv@SyfPL80v/Xk8mEv5LYhv@0APeMcn5ZR2dFOkcXI1EspW8vOR@cE8ktznAOmSzXae0i3gwLMTCLClbfkv8131C1v7VjFdB7uW6dT5D/SgmVpm@2FfTbM4ymWS1E3w6A1eJ9QvavJCs0ncTNzsNtfWnP6LPo@wkKVI@V62qW4y/aDmtWs0Fb8VStVoKXjYTifL1q57ZUQugf@RyyWS1Ci87AdgMvELaBnubYjXWhHvrzh2eSUm7uAhgZnOFVEbNYOogpzxka3h612e45weH9GURYDX5GH7Sh7OSRIa@S4TfvouLFfHOnUTPwO3OvZ3d5J07WjlzcRH6jMfgpS55tds902230T97cSG2RdoHU87De6Z0caFmyik1nnTcxBP8aCJklZBU9pFWp1zLwMa1XBGCfQTy29uFXL1eyIFPoRRP4pp6A9FvAb5xMV4VY@dUBrVU5BxQrKJ3dH8Q9GUcFNj5ZYwqlOXyyQQw0iTIgJcx/HOR5/LhJp9PAmUuRR5TLZd51CTLFRKlVNn/q22AVg5CDv9DSS2bym0Vt@6CzIt/3mzVhTy5em7U1MvauVHBWfXLatf//DRa5zDu3MmWgUSlTLUptNv3d4932@2aKIooKMENPYm7C2i0xI03qOT5cotTpFK9S9WslvIM6pPHkeIwQrASEF3RtvJqCYkkmH00vgMkEbi2tME2BI2eeBPKnHIb4AnqDGTeg4v1WIcN8GIDVN6YySy6mMV4ON273TCSwy8/NHyltKTfBT5GeAl@L8zyJgqD@NNHu3v7x2ltW2Ix7cHuXlo7en4vpuJrfvFOwVl8f7a/e//wOSR4@mh/92j/44NP958/BX@PnS2ugOn798Uz6lrxfsY@E165b3TD0I2pYbTPptOz1@yVabZNqExrCoVyBi7zjDaUZawvylWFX9f09FevdHdMF3v3w2@/@@F/9@53vvvud7797ne@/9Mvv/9t@P0Yft/lz@/@m3Ie7z/98p/97rvf/h3w/A/w@yP4/eSnX/7GN/iP3v8Yfv8p4vfH/i8Sj/8EgPUrP/3yez/66Ze/@gP4/Uv/94Prv1/7yerf97@1/ofpvve7N8f57r@F3@9xWEHc7/4298Pntfi/zeP96g/e/Yt/x///1P9D5@@8@xd/jDf/5Z/@4E//07tv/ntNK/3pv373re@9@9Y3333rO@@@9Y@1d7/xr9VM9Pa7777/B3/1h7/3V3/4P9L/j@n@e@/z/@4H//Qv/te/@N//4g/930/g9@/A9ZO/@PfQVf72D36I/9/7g7/9ox/i///8r/72D379b3/lfyLHb3LH//Mv/w2///Wv/ce/@a3v/NVPvvE3v/6Tv/nNP/ir/@NX/6/f@I9//d///l//k2@i52/@5K/@6Ff@8pvf/stv/fO//OaXa@7fvvH@5Xv4f/kP4PP@eL4PnPcp14f6fPlz4fP3ocYiF2gn0Lp/@d1v/BI08H/B2Ltv/xjPtcFvzf@PNZXi/Ji//X/AoV0vM4ZkwAW/X3/37e8iif4HIBH8h/T6TviyFMJfvrN4AbL@1opEv/zTL//5j@gtZlTqtGqDY3dJK6W2QL/ZKpf98dtf0IEkv7QMLQTg5/Qd5FBLYd9B3vbuh99496N//O6Hv/nuh7@Cg7eUK6d305J6y2oYRMy/RzyMWHifeBjxc8w/RVNsUupzeGOf@4Gff/650L5Q8ADl3Qvw/Zy8@MV4EB6w9IOCMPTHE5fsgkXdvjPjOzd93zBnxhovX7ZwvRX8MPcUyR5bgWiUz7JZykdsxviyDvpDpNkWOWd4J18Mngl4W/wvnDOBpWb@dC88UwsnOfx0fhbcKeQhm9QsXEwiWY1x6WiL@9A6MeWbKzMswWyWmoESDA7IIQVB90Acr9VSmLDG8YFXjlq9xAiVVKoG5cbUPE26XUIQs3sEBVLWUs9Ye6s24wlTCK8ekCMloNczUdXEVKl2HzKsze4zhIXACezLl7V6qTarI7i3nB6pWeoe4YTAaqlZ/S281wgmpBNi998CKqVaKlUvYYZYSF496TavpDwVjsqeYim/DuCJ2/137jL2kaiWRL5IsIEE47HxnlrExogQHcKbqS2/OPQfOOm3RQTfoKz8XBgP3yHZdIeLqxgB4EqSLMsMfrj@vsPuQvCMg0pRtvBIcQgpahHUAkIPhvNDKSFF9ZuiF8g/Vtv64AuBYWE2NzeFWF3MiocykU5RmHtSobMPuB0Q1YsKEwtlEb0NOggS4ALpq5T/ZhwX1uKMA2Yfpfjv7t0t9hEUk54LP4FJqayTc2IcynYqJWoAv@6khBeglgjQTgnQhSDParSQlxLSacbkWgzD2OHhoY8EebyoCSlo5lpWxXdcTppOpzFIIctpOZ32nzI9yUP2HTKF@k95E4lLXxVnmpargvZUZejFoqqOCiower59@xZqhfZXVQ5A@WT@VistV6JA8OB2ZCxrHhwY0nJlgWvmTC3kGEvQFCtcSZYUWIJtJQW@K58jEVyJuFYqxSkeUF9ObAU77woqNQecXo3VEdHg4iphKZ8MAvcO2d7h48f7T47HrRYTDPpKutEeu07X8LwEhu0@uc9PZGjlQjLWaCDo44qGDEbYr2SIGR/cf3ZwVGG80H4VJAixKq2r@sUsq0JsPP5sO@bvPBLxQ3@OeIT3yqJsCa2chaSxuhDrGqhZ4II5KsBVVhUee4N7zgx0@rQoptUCanZJmlRmwi86U4ZmaLnNGuhTeE5D3t4mCgj1c4mWLtAJtVUQ6nV/zx5ThfrR/jEkOD5kqpaRhfrnbCZjhtKlULdqlmEPJsNN3PwmNjNipEybjUwa/7RsFu5qrpBW88XWxoZ1LmGeTaq2c9zFeAmv5xIW46twMeGrAvsqeMEFeeDWRObvCz04rPqb89DgW4Lv0BPVPHSzpIDz2BycMI5eVWjdywtBQmzjiy8mrF4H/Vo6eCDEgFsMWbA/TTJ78lCmau5NXYNCB4z1zE9N/IKj3DO9saXPoesANWKXl5d9gHTwgGl1jV55ih7eL7vk0wH35UwXYnalUnur5oqCdlKpvM1qmgAewpaCG@A2oAHQPoIthf9VPcgkmy0pwKlUUYRHNpsVcO5YECqGwGivyNtMrSbxNpjNqbRVRMCPguizmhZeftzZR4u42QyPiyEQwAYTl2WCsCIP898KAr0B0XB3HH2Cuup3zsydO1mcxMjmMuFsBZWYXULdbGZzWaS48P9feACLr@Zsj@vZjLqtjMGpgzO3rejg7IAzv610wGmCs7ytmOCc1rNqZluZ1gUmbHOTrwwtytTEiTFDC9PcT6x7htWX8WxRTaQMNHHbN6FeDxLWe7We06Xvx1d7smnbhovnv3mCXE6sOjYaI6yhWRI6Mc8SyXNhUDujU@qCURvIaN/GtXVL6MkdpzeXvcncwlM6luPW4iAOxoOABXQD5BCc@9rJZnOVBmvJY2e8I2j5YqqhZmAAwZ9aSmvpDWOnWKz05K5l6O5OvpIvpXt4AMhf4trJZyoD@fPHjx5OJuNnBp0K2smVIQFahEPbTTulSj7fajREMdWgbFr49WvOnqSNDejTht6T4IkLYJ6klVqQuGe6tVo8vpNVNUmtZDOlS2FBOKQ5lrAuYNIUliyNdD/3OUDFdmxgNpW0njbPiQqVfr9/uXWeWrwI@rnE34A@l5Ke7pyHr1UpEq/CpmnJXASCj94Hcp/7a3sVUcuXxGqjungvFsRq61K4OzJ6po6HgZqZ8@upCsCUOdQYZNRkwmXFdZxJpWP0HddYRMyqhSAiR@h6hJx4GWbXzGCO59ezK0Qizc6vQ8nlxcswVYCWcHkJdOfEBrL79nzrtGm2oZZzrX1gQdB8tgNTvxgt9uKFENt69mm2XoeqPs8VtVw@l9eyhUK@qMF4U84V8iXobJlCJq9pACVXLpWLl9CuFeVtjL7kx/bOg/ZeoW8ZJPQKN8bZaLHk2yemdV7KShyPRLJ6eRl7K8Q@evapBgPk2isBg@6nmlSvZfNlcGXRpWUBYSZomqRlpawqqVn8v8Wh4f/7x9fgX8M7pMpqwjFa6HkCwyYM9TZ7hJY@Jg47dvBbTwN2z@iuibE31GlH857reN7fI8493T7hQfdNbhY3DHqo4wfvvJE5Ga6J8Xw8QuM@hvsPBmF/1AEEkR3yCPfg5lqOsypCkT1/uqaUj0ND9EAMbokeoj87@PjhceR5vL@791AosHuHT@5feeT9SHn2aP/Bcfha5KFB0nwI4hf3Hz26@uo/cofPn/Wnjos/4cHh89ziFnrhgVkhB9dypNCbgPg3fCXBEiQKUMTyxcChCnjM4g4ox3d8Z76wcGbQ@Rk/DWx64bZ/fjC8IhwHR4R1hpy2Y7Aut@GE2jrZV/RlebVYFoQxs50zVsywnmNZusucfn8DPIc6Hnc0UKC1LGyJmPWZ41q9M7NnbAiP8WRlWcUvpSMSwkMAMpp2yTYHCDNorRdGNZvhslTHmhpsOmZrPeGBXuh0zcEQxuAzJ4ggdHSdwe9DL0hvRK/JzR4Tngf5XQuxrkcXQKcrieKeKD7UJ3q96hovql6mUrlzR33qimVxDGOy7g2M/Rk0W/YcupHuztPiRBYfsPYAFzYsZ4wqiDdugMxe1hqtnZxWL2Xy2b/@rR//3Z/8@qCmNjN7GWl75/GjfAVYG0ixjARVX5iVSa3RyqV8qZzVSulSuZTLq4V8Pq1qadAIi2VQCjJqSS2U8mU1XcqVQQrJlSE0Xy76orASyL7KVgXA2l38cvc2aUbyEFQgvgzJ3iT0JIvp4fuUiQakEQVUQid0dHzLrMEAytQMyxYZQNRZl8UePNjLPHggivfwBbdx7GVEsYcv@VImU7wnigaF7JVQohIdnqaENhDFCX/JZO4BjaccAH4@QBSH@LJfwOk0UTTxZW/3wQPMp48vGqaHaCc8hL9YwUsRotn4AhI6AXgdQoNouzyfHCG6jy@YJYY84CF7ECaKHwfoYMgzHo0DeBiUdHdXFA/4y@4uhuxRsfMc0a/hyy5doujCCzR9URyAY@BCpxPFDjixA4hiF1zduQ5@@JV0tDBvT3RRnHPyIIFEcUax9e6JKLYDf8zmUx@bPFK3Qi8qL/VdeinjnyhqAdIYLRu@ZEUxF77koGwPH36qDyc9Y8CvucufXSjpw4dZ3ZxN9x90Pv64Mxh03Pnu/sfPMGhv7yFII/Op2xl0/ISdNlwOpNp7qOkno/nVC0p90G5XdGtl0Nfa7ZxuXwlqz9sGYgipXgNm/jXAjEbtPQjae9i@q69aRiaAbez7I3h28Lo3guc9vcODgouC6DnrdMQqNn9FaSYE1BdwARi74wnwUjs90ruuU8X3WY1l0iiyzBuFTKtKAWwEcn@meonh/QTedZz7SZ7PG7NaplWb1Yoa34fUT4jNmZY3xfTGaEct5ysb@o6q5VKzClqvcPpxFpfUHZZQ72y9YYknyR0NdACxubMjiQ21taOppUqh@GJrKorJCt53ssXKm0QmnmEMb8lGsbVTzEdSFIspXdEqxSJIYkCTCQzoHZySaScSZ4Z@kkwitjRBAEWgsrI5ldOs9hOz9KzG8WLzZHVWU6vcsjLLXAPWQzP@0@7EcTnIAYCb7WQquAKfENVySQQEFCWRTIZMD/R1YbEF9LOvH58cH39OIl/dn7t46hrIvar@68cP9@SDw@ANDfDLD1ASdVx5D7nWUggXSQOvY9BB5IcwiII@F/jhKUHXseR92jkH4mwQENgAkn1juPLxwyU4R0PnjOeMRhaqZFHR7hoMv09g9pheq4NL77EEYcX05BkN3@16vdaujcgOARQxSPU1Rsb7F2AOPI57aPqBkp/jyTk/oF3LXFY7tVlsBnDaNSapL0dO76WW6lZ7@FmCe7V7mLjahmenatQM13VcEbRpsdrfsWtT29P7xlPDRaMmB4ebIEzgcbpEnxnJTdbcx9h7qKlcSnWX2QvMnkxHCV2qd5LLXjgvF3ogcRJfDwp9Tic8cY/GZbVfY4kXEPU1vLubLNGT7yV3clWg0z3WToJX5mX/ZZ9prJCrkqaRQFjQlYg@WG6dJWv1r8GDwz6pVAAbv6JPACpmBoDNHgVA7LF5We3WLJaQ2IwliUi56qDWwOQXeNuWRLElSY2LllCXpM@EOvTX6jym17xph75owzIdVcsUqjPwU4u56hCqV38xq7q18dQ1qha8@tN5/DCrXgWiAu0AzJuLxLtf@kZyW8rXuF@VQF1YIHi05XZtVrXRRiY0jFq2BgGpRi6TBh0ebsU0jPlaIa0W0tl0Li0V0RcG/HQ@DZ6g44B8kbASImNiOjPLyGpaNdR0IvPS7L1Mpk8SILUQ0VgyPXH27emIgQ9UFbZNeoUnkCelbVmge/Ucpm9L1FiBZVSxYED1IRub6SGCemboFqVIJiWW3UpYmwmMs3k8He83WpXK/mz8dQhKSK93CqliJvUmmawmNpI1z3gt1KtCHdkLlXq8AS3Xn@lk3nTUgFoGl1rUKo1GB4tYzKSzmSyUzmxfDLbFuthKZzYKKlTRJSO2wTjfiE7@ocSz8Bu3Ufa2DKg6taxVBZlm4rIlTSor@a18hs8G8pTC2GdvSEmWaIrBwe1EPF7U4vFkvIrrEBuiP/EMPI34WRy4a/yOuiOCMCZWxLKGERaskc7mZgLsQBy7FFAoZDlQbc@Fy/PL7brwFeEIT1xuay/wr/ji8e4h/n0FvMrwWnrx@Pnh88MHAlNoq6fcjlU3qnK1XYUXSa7fFWIVxoCTNn2rUsoGYx@6iTS1XX/Bn008PQBwBbJ73WAt2txlmKi3sU/RYsEOi0MZdHfU0LRsq6EVYewDbhpE1TS1iqs0MTyfINehMrxzwG87VcfDfl9j87mekgJl/w5jg9Tmzaduinlxm9XFUiFLR9rKAhEzdjXybm138Gw32M22u7ca5OZYwQnt1YF1kJ5OTlT/jE8x0xarMdYW8/5husU5oBxg5J@0yxU5Wk1BFHE/Xew8Hotfwl8sHoB98SY4NVQQqyeZ8vbSmaJycKaoqLXFF8yrnqDdz20hdpdOTmr85CSLhWcncWHYX9PJ5gosWQ6WXL4SvxuLx@O4tlFh3ttYbFUJT6piPJuOF9NxNc3uxos@VatvxFzkzOCL9osYbvZ/UX1BGFMLDo61fe2lBp0nZjuBB2iPOLMHg3s@j2sJMeXl2PtCK2UfHxza990HkSNWL@ox/PS5hKfFqpUX7Y0TFTpNVsyepGPsboxOGIhlwETjHlABJ0wFLKAimPj8/uFjMYf0qqhx8EoA1Tj@kGlz42LDwcUjFm5pfGt/8nXGxvFsDiqjWYvNajl/r7xar0vqtoa27IqsAkNkXy1ImYs6ZwJ1CihoEPLul36Qm22X4F3LqPCuafmUVq@rWxpLxsbvvvx9NEt0vv/p7iMWxyWHv/uTH2nFv/uTf0W78uKXtAyhZYsxiIlOtVCMnZ@Pz88v4eJh@VgrxpHKFZPg5ktiaqyuqFrWtu0qqyi6vlVM5bS7dlXx46pFNRnzpJi/ETVbyEuJhKoAVlvZUiYJYRd@TC1TgrdgMY5HFwtQUVCA/WdmXlPvbu9A@XayOa26AU1ODQ/rsvBv2/DKqBQ/fnnBGLx0673BwNTIpSis8lZi22@lbfYWl8LeShvsZa2OWypUPOIbLBVt4ZFHXC6N11PKVpyBSsnqjcvqZStFa02ger8wjC27eaXVNjfwzMuy15YNf8aWR3@YKPDw4DV4M7ZeeWJiK6kovZ54vTdsGyxfhwazpSwOIrOtYAWJ/0lSM/nul35D0wp/9ye/dtG@aH@ugVpeLhdULfazn21P7aln9Oo/AwA3mKQJVGuSrtF2DDpClZxxS6Omnyp0yF1RiE1tVD94/EBBR5WcgehmDmyjRwq6cIriJlVum1tF7CUo2hZarEiT@kJWyJJVQQjkfK6euINummCwLTSP22glhXPhqxgE0gwDFacqfHUBCjxGIL843bZnTd0xnRlKUDq1lWZ3IAnk8FU0OLlBljb8oVCCMUHZup6Uo@wR1Ug0ZSPD89B8JYziwlchiW9D3JqzsY5GYTCmacPYK2MUwpMCeg3IuwV5WzxBm3wTVHoeIc04djyRDSqM8FWQxogKJghpzNyGCFXgX18FAkAZEj5gs8W2WTbJzs1UqrqwjXmJpxvQeqceGKQQMBlC66EBlCBxFeOBF6hO@NVabBd@DYOMHPEMgHAYfDNEDZQvTE5vKPeSxZj3BgWwyDpbgorG7txZYFWrmb0koxIh/BNzjFOHVA/2alwBWKC4ftSriGmGVkergW/Y7IDiKUIXWp3EzY1WI0mZiK@XggD/791osUVeqSoKqGIB/PrivaILJIPESHZeh122XWOqVkyyEPku4N4lpMgsQKiNN2cfydrnQeAlYPizWPBNKGBax9HpWL/dXrVIwkBXmeIHedAuHWcGviURbnkOmd/BJEgdpoKimBbF7psu6Im0SyMwepnIqklMtjASSngQH9dyDI8B5JP4oFQYm8FTR@ONfj4bZHSq60CFemPHJmuPZI0Kz2BAiwAe5RvK42hP7TP8gJtfN5Q4ipFHRvKw5SPGZL3SQbM@lBa3SXRcQz8JaJNmxkBm3VGPaWWWoIZGBv3sEFySEhHCHVA3kMYdyxgBSkeGQQf3vIqiDEAEnXbIquFjE9rV8IEJI5DtKfc5gZUz88RUjtGSsuT08XwftxETQ6kVux/fkeFbELQc54RZ5onBZ9kTSxZ2PAYKF@gMaaDs4geEreBWHy2bxnkfEJ8oFvyK8ChyZykdSbuRmCevP7PqRqKNNXpB440JtWIZp7odoS9dF4I/0@DNvcBGF1magnc5ZLmGb52nFke7G6HZKcG3NlYjQ1cyrt6ME2JMDKx0oVMYu8YpwzkDAccYYJrdwN4N9mIo7VdpAKC@Bz0LjXdO3ApaaQJM3F6iC13PZ/A2@4hlNQEjchNqvrkzgIFVX1uGDmGQFMvhTXpQMTItWSBfgd456kEY2gfxmx@mD1o3usmw6qJ5sw0fHA46lFeN8W4RvOQjL9g7sD1T0TcgsAAYrsBkIyGmAGxKTIocdJj@anLe2gXiJRV2HVKaIQSf1ACFRAUdWQ5aZ4x8aU2AgHu6xz/H4Zv2PDs7k8ne7NQ1ZcPDr495jq1bynhggujtKBNjNPa/82x2lXEAd@GS@EcH5fFwvDND6bZWvjPnT0HoezV/w1Qi3vfiODie4se1BiOyTYdG4TxqUA9M@jBfN@Hv3@LtT2ulz4P2V8H2J5XilwiEMQQzS8/T3TQAS3e6J@n@Wa/qB5xShwTgUItG4IlWoN3gZeQFLnPcD2M4E@SjYVDHOqE1cIAk8gnyRda8hEHMefDqv4/NGSSyjTO267r6PEHhSYyNDTgxJ7GHzWHYpxBwoqnyc26S2Jw15q2l5LMwOQxq4Q4QFw3PCec3A@X2qTF8xsNnED7j4bNFpkG2jVmLi2TodYnFwVaP9kqDmAhmHsS55LacFyEEGeRxUKnID2POl/wu4detUeqA3vwN6rEWNAxoE2MguJFQGi@ajWbL9oyzrVZKGUBjF4kQUOMAutEimp71QjdS3zq1xo635GWjmVoYlXy80as79FsDbytYxrCCqGFweploWXQw8reqcIHALzBAQDkMAlE02J0kzGQ1tIdOgdBwGuKCxhyxho9Mi6QvP8j3A3GJk54TNgqoFQGE/mGRAE0IYUHP4d@aDLjDZ64DcYK4En0eb4QW7uKtOFDySlfhvKZKlRTBSpICNIHsKK7WrhYlCIeqaFwJihTz0q//KPobH4x@H/rFauypwfIBoypEuwruDgURwu8uRFVWr0XqFTBQtnTLcGHk2ufyqT9aQzZbSqBm8HywCN6ZOekOE5HK7yZ5/dAZVNEWK2FTmNdqUMR5jXdL3i8CknKCh8k8P9k8aAh@es5AAEZmZTLDTzaLJpvVapxxsNmaZGcRJGeE5Iwn4bFna5Bs@clAezoIhhesnhZIp7h9VQR4Kh9GQQwai8zTTw3cUPAKrW/iooyf54LnUCvw2xCK2NjOuq2VuTciSEeY1hUA2BCvAejxz1ZXhKsMT5XCt5BHcVIGPIq/@c2A8wpoYMSCq9xCdSJsZKQDg8AvpmgcgL4rphqCqNLEOv5l@E9MB57BT73umVmOqS57ZtJX/v5BPFtI2UgHjUgfaiaHDBk1mee2b9o1KnPE2O4UFByQ6jpnDkusELbBX5n6SZWO5XSUkY4bg/BjttxXHs@Tgf6AS1Ps7tiZ6BMnl6twpcmkZrcqf64zmAPbwW9gRazUg6zXcwzPjk@gUrvOwDY9I83QgOiJ4asdhv/ZDCEqJ/tOxxMEf4saV2MRNG9XKOq226ZtTtrtBO78TFbCbey0ERSbZzwuoP4Lrkh6YE8@0MNxwum8MrqT5O0w8ZMLfrJjs3uSOBz7gThVu8uAh3VB/ofQIUgwzHMWmiOZc0dRujNJ0KdChs7IGYDUN/VkAVNfAX@wgI0I6eMx4ZJmOqq0lciHN6iXJLppPekn/doHJ2Vf0xJ6MkyvLQNYIkaauVdpjJR1V2TXXpsdTxbkd/Th@B5F8T26GV/Swq/izFXzGg/8sKyziQUEiLhAI3s7Glh04Fu9a@gsoRJ6o1zFE7w3ij3aeNdDTHch6q4fXe5D@0iHbx68hYh/uo7@N1dgkHz/fatPh27PjubAb0a4hzVBny30ghXmBEQ/SCLvuZ5d2LTvv2deEBe/GPsARQgQY4lx2WiJGjrmGNRuL5xADgDf0uZxr9u1dk8b4Go8cAVO7mmanWjrq@h@u2dY@tzoJfyY6QjcoMTPQGEjfvV@BUdGR0zP4bpeAsauZBgKwzgSnUeqrGkyevo0mVzfrHgUM2w9NFNOGB6spx@GX2PNOMVX47PVoAfE4zGcjj01cfpzPB/P/9/uvm@tjSTZ8xo9RVrCjcqUShI2mBYWtgBhawaDD2B7vJhWF1IJqi0ktUr8Udvu75xzsS@we7@PsK9y3uFc7VPMxi8isypLEjLunt3Zb@ebNqWqzMjIyMjIyMz4I8kOupKzTstRWX9kJBFH49sEITrI6ll2k2adeeLzMB936R4rQlzWS3cZscgNRISnmh7D7yPRt3tKg2tVqppRzqTT/Mwe8XDeiFtcYXhSLqPux5LfYrp785zFagIsEWHb37eETEGGWUyrlbchypu5I9bvTckEvONzut4dq0pzhkCNa7KkG4W83Wb9wslgZ9ygvzhwekd/AfA8GDWFoUzfcKal08Aq/nLpDyytRb8hJZ2gWFQUkms0rFIZ80zFP3@N22zd2WZrqs1Wqs14BqSbtAplWqkm9ShgeOYNQTfojO6QzviEvTP9mSe26X@9vj/EacXnpXCpErpq6XqpQgJ5KViq1PMklJfaS5UdfoiWKkf88Gmp8ld6SObW0pelipkWKDCkn/zwAu@1CMfv1lJlO@98zYz8T0Fk2vWWKvGYUpnn8pMpQqRAv0lrxBVbr6@7ORoGtLCxUukqcEzkYvvE5zAu/1ei/0viLk7pg48443zEhdWyKqcWDWvFkHZo2TApI2bM5IpezesHu2xWFhdBM8u0x7PrMHhSw3NLaWEkiOEr32jQX0IQcrMyGyNlrWT3REe3ThzKg5xun6nnsT7QzvP3Eyp8mjTC2dp0fTNeaRAygPfDE5XvwnMKHdMcY4Q7WWcGWiDqz0tzOoWxTuOiR98eIT7rThcibAumiIwSg7VkOulwfDmHxgb9QZpJ@CvcF0K7Dh/KyaQE905UY6mgZ@Ydn/m17hkEgz35nXndseoBtZQIwseT0qnMsnhdYFmMT4msszRVmXyEgiVzaIYHrU@cCW9HP3I5ETcurxV3LUOmrjTJkistJqmyh7hgV/5IWo83r3VEC/u@7aupeYuzljwAWDXjVkS@9r9Df@@L/m4UakOEiQZmKdazl9Jp9XruKjuBeTdpdnoA8dFVO85M5ShuISE57Q4szXwer02p@DD5ECVfGo2hT2j7hmzxnuAbdJvcWwgsaAnD6/TLTyv08tPK3YSa1ki6155RWjy0pOFIx2NMk67Nx1U6PmuI8YXPt/3udw/wMD3A9uABHndgOEFymeXDqx5buSRzm8S2vIFILVeUCHK@Lo2HOXlJ4p6vbuNrW3px0DzcOdjf@0CL7tOnTx29Ro8T/DBrcdYar@MCmW3U4/VgxrZlxUW6Klx24zg@uugPRw8@9rJTskSENSkDPrVi2E/PcUfLMkueT8xdqidlLYpqWJ@SaeCnpBJUHR9LdqjpOiKCBKP8I18DMeot0dvl3ZrDiZmazZ5/GTSbvHyZFNZ6FcPQmBtx5@@5B8WraMipmiWr2E0mwwE61M6Bev@qdqyOX9XV7tvtv6oPB2/V@9r@MWIzvHm7tdfYVvRfff@orjIp00lkYMSGkui6E7QCpNVVK6XSE8WQt/uDscid/LYj74/8S/Wq3wpwTfUs8i9fXMgPrxeMNqVWnbajY5xhhpxx8zIcwd6CU0TSNhbKTZtdLuFUoajsGe1pL7Hnvey3w05IZTPY@w7CIDJeeqob0giSvDWO6q4oScgGyaZDnOUVFlg3VN2n8ri7ITC@2F@BxCgh6SPbntKEi//33RQ8rh@@PlII87F9sL/TOG4c7B@p3YND@vnmQ2P/JdGzcXR82Nh6i09c8PXBTmO3sV3jF4JAyVOIv/HLVTSai4KH4kyV1ifcfHsDGv74V/rUGxq8uvHZ@TRSS1c9SJ/Q74a/Be2ljcxVBPUFDq98VaDyi7XDl@9ozVfBr7jhNFfBbH@QfRtxhtLFknrGrdFk2aT5tqGnKy17hbLD9xGXY4UkRcEGx@XI87OrDHA24mmHgcpuw0YFZ98SvoPnsgFNDT0g2ABlDFaqipOLLS25zxjkJrXW6vYRa1VaEyNC/QNVXxhTk40MU0zbygAo3EYaPZwHlTfiF8T39GJFNzsaSgH1OH4hBdQTeQFVtAHbEbWqS1yNDq4gntWavPjlcrDL18Lqafxiy@dd7LrGScaNh9RXcXJGBDPpcgo5OeXhNLec356rRFwe6dW6XZkYgST2JJkoV4ls20YlsyRsOrhq0GZvki8bX4kbYCfkd0aRylcdTx3DOCjohZK877zr98QEKjHdYd5T64gbVdW@7WGc9I4dcQZ9ZkAk3EzjEdfb0VphcN96VHNrqkVf20hy4lljgvYtBLamEPgjYAhQIbXTafFKxf7AANPvaFbOR33iSJzb/m6XJ3ZuX7WCVAVttZX/JfztN0cT2U3tk4ydImNHQ/RbMCS1kq8yO/0hzXEWq5wmDFKwddEfjEIZw3y6B3zjxMsclcbCRq39XN1MtQY6TLbY6/esRs@Ii@9o9YyY8j6tMsfL3XksvpL80cT5tAiL3R3Q8c/614F1d@biEukmwPELKcJ8V47Dz/GIMRH9M5PIjt8V0s6uVzd3tj4Wfv/ZRe5ZEQuS@tkYHeI/Yky0RdOD7/nYYHEIvUvPNJMzMLo6Q21tg6elJWa5AUb7wIuQ9nUvmhvxNzE3nn4PJ6XJ9/zyy5eq1CpAMul84dFFPpFurjoxTbpc51RpExBLdhKyJOvz5o3LMGN5/QKOSRgFBELqQY5g3z6RkU@LENO7s6sOSRadGFkPdwzfUZtsUZFklYfDkT0exZ/yW9XlTaeYGJQoi5x5I6JdA7nsOJZZCq9XU@B25oMj@X1/cOtzsZPl4bug7cyF9l24FZbvhiXLkgXr/mB/nwNWFrc/BJb67t4NWBbJaWgxp8fM6S7mYmva@S3@PDV2PPcIDNZenKDEQK3Wrnp8RW0il@elgmODSRSio@Od@uGhysr@hOqS3MOWoa3FIGA/UG8Sa9uwx8LOi5WmeLMcK0/mTcqiLXHqunsyzyTeHaJC6yCupkcsLJL46J3wVqSeXllYhWDrexaIhnJp7D4bGRSdaMBfaQ9IyCaDZnUwM7ObOVl8wsg2Atd0c0U3tm342cJa1m6kGx6ObUC2TZB/Ds@S2eP3XvTjimlHFCxEj0KH26RJ03pD@4QjanhABT0vPYJzhsUMKYzsRcHOGdrB8KuU1rD/PEMxI4kSLrqwJda1cqxRE/140ag5bJCIZcCHpaf@KBbN9MGIeH7zzB5QJ1n08ukliJRMJKB9YXMFVT/9qpcwpka8TlZjhdyea4uMzYnB8hSnsxr2xt2FHsIWem1SPEw2RdJ2blOFf0xTskqkWjI0n9kZ85Egr62uPv4W7MlemOqFPwtb1pBJ@Tm6HND@PgEZjSM@3ifObey75nvCAHNIJ6b1ZsJMVCRVZ8aakuo7L0Y2foSLnAsRMgj3j5y@k6066nYCt9nQZUWyoXORqT5YUzjuqMyaKep/nd8cBPI323vw/e3JZEMhmA5@hVX@6/4wChKvPCtSjvUKEQbS74LhsMfFxJ/pElDy7MY019mOve3E4FV6hY9832b3pKO9k8Ts1jVnDdwIHy96SOON072NyeO9QnnD7upuY6@uHnH4z07qLDI7zDqW7HkQ9uYhwDKYzyWwfLAP38OoQv8RDq4BSWRib74808b5Jm5MEdKaTzgflDYL1bK1PDn6najl9xBbxc0@jFTW/YEq8ils/WDXmXWyXtpI1SfkokEvT7XcbMHLclV6hwNdQEqDkNHEe2vBgqeGsZSEe815H/ZRuNgKbuX0jC0n/WJ5vbT2Y4Z713NH7uXJj6fuo1Y1q2jx9XuX0dXwpv3pvH9x3VFdNfjl7LY1/u1XpVafqMfU1soPEoO5vFYtctjbp/TvuvqxxJyrEXzO8aSRVtqTfLtKLalkH77xQDn8wJvmCjwkJrhUPbo0XAgXu1H18mTttNqrljYuT3qnG3DyGy1XR8vl5Txe/ECrKMkYuZk/GZ1iTbVPXYPetUKkU87rql1DFLuG0JvX/jDs79X2X6ZO46AA4AhM23rzgbqk8F6ANRt8T7xecJPXx2SuAsdmoCBlFtgrqIyQAHyejOOYdkiY0ai4pM1Gt/zv2MkslLyrwajPX0xcS7CW@hJ@ySwYN6YSnyhQkZPQRL@EfwHBScrkcTEkb8diRV0oi7pWhu@kY4E4QU0Wh9mP2Sx8CoGo9uU6Oc1EXuC3LoAEctZ/4Wrq2TPOYE@sFnl8igdTDn/IDhOlUzziAoT@DPi2AU2w5h6x20eGuo/fZTzIGz6jGrGfDBvIZ1hTxBeYf6vP7N/E9Z8RAYTwC6JzefqIU2tepEiK7yAfLiBoXHrjj2sGuFXKoCygs4At7VUT4GwpzjRCs5pM9H7hBuQUWtH/dA8KZf411Y24vCPFmSR8T61/RaAlDyl/2sSfblItb1UrmGqmsEWKhW9SAyddtD16HdC0GqvtoNslpIUWCwk58Mj@vbr95bj96ARtnsbIy/fC1PdC6rsn3wWppJRHC3xSqGIXyuY@J@W@qmxSzJ1qq6pYefFopFseqSRJ2Y15ZSNv1G@GSeHNeCiFK@MPz1IfCtaXn2aMvnx5kKoTM3j8/US@a/5e0SMfY5kq@yLdPv5m9AAFbDyrbU0muNTrhd3nGZ3uXH8Bm2WJmkpJdU5jqcykqmofTC1OSIPDOT9P281qAmW5bCQOz5ns5rMXWU8rGc/zk2iIF@PUxJoxRywqcZvLTLhbdlikdvjzAwsEwwSjKTNzN03lsa48tsCi1APTrHhBTk1w6trkFK/CL/IL/jGTPY2cKZeb/XFBML@Vzot3c5pALHQfZGeTKS1N4C4iL3Wn5qwiSdvjSYizhcS@dQoctxmID3YHx@APYjlhCwojKaboHn/RlE4KlA373jWE@Pg18/fio8xLn3TsQTe4VTVsM3z2wsqkHNxHQTSKEF2LA/9EV4NBF7eOrPDdsAu1TiuwsorrlgSitbJ7mQYse6S8iyftkE6VPHUAyDcwEEk@RFfn53Amgwds/waiFScu4cjL1HpjOdCgOfN4RdzMA4XgGyyAu@G5jYSMnMweUDoa@K3Ay5COFpH2k5GudkKd/JXP0@E3giButKRVMpl/uQpbn7Zf4j73abn0uGyR7FpfB5e8x08SBysikvmwgjiMq@UnmYx1N9ySu@ECALpqDwv9O@LN4Dro9YJMjVYMLhiR0hoFw@ug7WUyh0F8CQy4YGXcTMIPu381bMnhDildPjEjvIQjV67DiMPwF@uzXBe3@K7MzeDSKrltpqG@DtsgoPE46fRxO8wXFggTIPRApctgRER55Kg0Snz3rHFh3eUSB1FEDcQ5se4mYjL0@qOwRSPDJ1mZLoGSa5CksV57AhNqr9X14RzszUIA7jEJBQwC5ippHg4ZfWn@XTgo3TFzx@6bkSmS9OvzXKHpHgxDkr4JgXlUuJqFOw3w8avGkTo62D1@XzusK3p@c3jwrrFT31FbH/iOGxflHNFYvTrYI@kS36bLrfkBvcjWjqhmlj9kavsfVP1vbw7rR0fq4FA1Xr/ZaxA0An9Y2z9u1I9c1djf3nu7w7fvBEHtHxyrvcbrxjEVOz5wuVVTLZPUUwe76nX9cPsV/axtNfYaxx@4xd3G8T4aw61@Tb2pHR43tt/u1Q7Vm7eHbw6O6gody@w0jrb3ao3X9R2P2qc2Vf1dff9YHb2q7e1NdPTg/X79ULGRgNXLrTphWduiLSxa4n7uNA7r28foUPK0TcQjBPdcdfSmvt3AQ/1vdepO7fCDq4Ee1f/lLRWij2qn9rr2kjqXyX@DKjQu228P64igBEocvd06Om4cvz2uq5cHBztM66P64bvGdv1oQ2X2Do6YYG@P6q5CakpummAQteg7PW@9PWow3Rr7x7RmvH0DeweHBvk9EYawrFHVHSYwzCDQWyLSweEHQAUdeABc9f5Vnd4fgqZMrRqoAIuK7WO7GDVIRDy2u6n26y/3Gi/r@9t1fD4AmPeNo7pDA9Y4QoEGDDI@EOtQo2@51xgnwkseiVkzhnNdHk7V2FW1nXcNYK5LEwccNTS3MNm2X2mae4h4bB2ihH2cGfiX9sFKZ/rVdYAYn9MnMrPPaOKISdsHO3VakXWwq2zy4S2tOusToZTsb7TSxB/pZypkTTs4uzpvhr1OHz6mcTU5@LiMzl0kXHKQreZjZk7eMX2@whVyuWbzXa1JG92jZtNx71Mzhca3auhj8HmlHN1HZLPAzhsHP5WK0P1ZilCbP@iLTjbUwwUESgr1fxDTN/8ycFSx2A50NTjvA7A5Oork2uQCVykkGtnZEWl2kib5ZIJ/h5oduGLegPdaTZyTwjKSC/Uj@qf3Jfkhi4P1gqSzHHcVi9jEMhrhb4FpRhrhkAj8j45IEHa4SS8Kgk/n@ZLdHPb83nm/3847jqnDZUe0DzzPO9@ofhacT1QvTNZnZPnaWSeCiMy@m1WY@P5Zk0zpcfGG3LM8/mmO@I9jsJGYDzg15ab4sFofWuZ/kOqwSHKVDm0B9woeZOh8r2t/a7zHbq608mRj4v2r@L3MLdgLIhowLXgnXO@U/7w6lQI0wTgWB5Ek1BEyikWrjrE3iQvfUMELFLoJ27D8obX6IuB1nUhCiuyV37XbxGo8DG9t7EkOvzysvd56u7tLohPYPllffbq2kYnDbv3Nlb8f0A4H7OWoYwNax0lP40/WLNkmxYdnihUvPWF/ZuBiEQURCd8MGr9EnIfYbiNtyQRBhu5GyDnVg4leNgAdsooDcDzIGH6dOTM1A@RTXXXQm0v/llV8n3Ql5gFtzNId86jd4h/Ajqe/meJxhzQDaRbjEMbEubS7YLmX3TWmory54cA9KOJlDR9LGLeYBnzUxfaz8K7lX5q3rVGMxJQR85WHnWsSEg8msVDGrqInM/sNxxnRB8AcPYze/E3zGz1@0AHuONydH41qoyMi425cE@fUyWG07vSJhnyKzCQIqmZaeqZwyu9opHju6ePkODCINRsYFaTZgY1vGvBGHEdkskm2gH2x5KjPwqkI3gE4G5pj9W/i3Fnd0VA2TPwQ/dtEpVACKw5yIlS7idvImCIf4jgWhpwpMv0pejD8fyJNZsB/RjtOgp5QywoCeC9KMlShFW1fmSjhjblosG43Emrarz4kYL7aA3MRd0zf3tyKfw2RQI/O2Lz4wGEPO/kZBACT42DDnr@xSdqFT1unF1lHV8c9Sa91OcgrvVaYpWIKbmHt1GW1yzV3K/jhKEfOmqwG96iqeiEbtzOe9bRlmtjKq4dRVsA5Jv5H8REfgMQTnrn0QqxWJzmrpGeZkQM61JK14LTjiEmkln6989bukbJCZKZkv775MoQi0JvAZ7qfnKKlr8Q8Nx1xkVdidcxR8BCWHdtkLD46ZN0ZG2J2A8B52ObDEGRxGd1ggegKdA7Vl0BT@YdsKIJGEqvDJM4gxK3jEWl5Wb2JseeTSXBojP3bnmQECORUy5TwJMCHxtB2l/fUa39MKHfv121hseKjo74L20U0JscSuj4y1rT6/SGpjj76TTi64djx1Ht96BD0oquhjl9I61k41CcSRumnZqA2ye6dlxkJxc@oReEI3gptj/mDu3QZwEJUwpPcFtZUnpjX8OimOXQMb5fLKv8s@fKMaMJhSZmIz9Sa@vJFSglBdcjQgCkYRvHmgm02uR3cO8TT76Y//IS1HypQrx2048ikFkg@C5RBavQ4xmNrJF0f9CM@0aChwAlITImyHKTFhqq0Rj/V7KTtmrJJdEzELuWefH87MZMaaylqKGFc3Tox31qBBhNUWtGhQeNgoeWVVUZl1obr652bMY4Wmr62VtmPvVikVESJqD40qiOeRG7GTx/wpA/5qw8jzB56gzturYICYeisuFedlnOMH2wK3ofBsG2fiZIm0/YHOH7jrU@/x7xojg512L@WP4qCMe0AWsXwtsgwmvm/9C96ze1@1z8P@6FP@zTE0b8ViYfHMT9iwM6H/ZuIkzHxh7ZVqD1OniW@jIRhw@/4XnLDCs0VjYJB3jZTGA3HtQsJE8En5zACTBLBMn8PJmOkxXWerCaVMmn/U7bHKzsbd9Z9XJ5VWW70AUALuM0JCwrxIR2xY5LlfLoxVeBsXgELxzNVUL5zh8VeCuMfiUR8DZPC2CAzZZZgdwI7szsxPmnfum2OQThEoKVgJ0BioSjPr10fubVJijyHpUBFlddLVlW5RblFHEI8jO8m98rTfzL2hMCfQL/8eBa3zGIEFnEdE20pkv2KjjJKuLB5YMgymiUxSbHwPOxZ7oecxeN2Emr68/guarDlDylFOszeFFdiRuZp44OcgfkmiZzm2MGisqSWHI7bARWkNsqX7mbY4Fv2szz5cYkrJ2cQTNsact5C@i5StYhKyF48YV5roywxlb89Y1ZW7jtqEwSszjI5s7Jo57NGc2EPlFDWV1xr9YckjLMT1NOmHkvRqD9Yuif17pQdMyOzzaJ1y3G@aQgszFalxfJRm0lbHeNxvJGZxGeCadIUY0sz4iFsX/k5ZvNJIt5Wm5hv1eb4G3S4i2aJ3VS8qMTj3Za5j0XxGha9ZqGJpxTjjiClG/H7kyZ1vHm3BNEwZXvVZInRhMhojuXRAjVBpphK96cQc5/GfYIebaIc2m0T7ezxuZOok0ZyJuSp@ZQKcgl6InA7nDZJLg06ML5AmDjRcGMhFSuct@6Yr/LKhTMEGcYHAQitOCgk51BygpsM1gQfcXaATr4Ja6EyJBE9bdoWDnHQ/5hgHJVfH@5oi4fmuFA@3RBItzEk2lVwqXmQjL85/Txp3jKUKVLQFJ9BirhHU7Lp4v69@rN9oXIEQWrzZ23pW3LRGUctEzb0j/2peQsdOGlK10zNqPREaLJooLlAu5TzbiDbVWh/4VA4HtYNehrRBkJe5/FnWddAOO@1UkxtVLltj1HE0eSW2eaowqZUSRhKfoP8eiqKqssbVwIQCMZUv1omCAhrytjjUoBD79icl0JUjxFVrJYxLeklR0VN7DxnfAdRdYEnq1aJ0qwSP9owCjOBkGIxu0yCCOkss4skUGihm4mLVeLp7P4kJUghNrwvFKeh0KOSpmE8ckJATttdchKJclJWbklzMH98suqkPsb8zV9/LFlfS5NfiT4xhieF8uTX9VLqa6rZlZV01VRNoodjt5r6SKRwbIRjqfDn/seuKXbI89gm1NpkpLQMbZ@NtOq0y6R9m/dLpJ6xU7bRMQw82zPcbL@akmIlFZR9fgB2tcRXBojd/qd7ayxTDSY6VwDHpTPOLnnZELLGmsVSj25hp2si7cUBCsyett9R7453d1NhX8/GxtDoMhiulkolMPGZHfze2FbjKCnsF9Oli52rbrc4uPnL8N1ZkWV/EHBKgIrZQQc0JDQpIq8/PJfMEMCBiqJ0QTuyYq9/1enYKRhwQ4nBo2GTkjoaguIFKIyNXt4d8wEQg9QL7M/oIPr3s4pn340viqaGYq6hqDZMgq@z5vaMyIMXHdhnxzdVDAyC2Vgz0brlVDc/YwVBZhMeLA5f7HxOzJOzr4Jut@@q90jnjEgBC18nK@zu2hVKUgQ3jOzdexVxPFpXBddh1/IrRhGb1wHOLEwmz4SJC4/Y@IfBef12kM@e/JSlZYW6vIxuLiM@tauy51lHB4u/B1jhQ0L7XqUv/UG@xXSaLExLvZ7ByRNh9Ljsztz7pIo4fCamafbt0iDqbHQ9DtZAXXdYFzCx7Hl4uSd3FI@Jm/14W@6AhiWBoXFCzJX71YCr2T9PLF6POp37SUVOAyAD@10SUTKh/DmByHcAPAP19CN6Ior2Xws0rXcnAoqIgoNkHdNyBxWaqJDJPGxVf73J12o1tThYXla12hY9FAqqtlVTO3ixtaV26PcWfv9QXVld3RCZu@N8ppdb5uVXtUUw@IRzuXUx3KGf9K0KvzFYa2OIF4vVRXdjsVl9trkRFU9qW3Drp6f//Lf/@p///t@KNf3jf@DHFv84@Sku5HlecbH1efGHrxv4fbJzurR4drI4OF063wCX/Z2jhvcbo4KfmI96w7NMTlYB6y3bkZp9Nkef0VWVSR546Q8/kXSpqFwrKub020gyR7GMzbUC630AP8oz2sKbpAOTW3lCIkdAxziOp9FpBTDAo/WGKEm4wA5U6svdijm4RziYuEB8q5LTkXhYZ70O4NOSRFKALy6tWIWwFwU9nIBfs84r3ctkfPobjpqaf4s/vY7Ot/q36tHHvHpUUo9c9Sib5T/ltR/prbNYDOGdK8VoO5DNuvQluVqAmaGKQlb0eP/AuXYmyJ3JLHLKHkAyYSq4sHjBufHuj51lJOFadJ5ZQC5TJUckfMmEKrnPi72vNCyfqcTXbMrVhhWFpt7FcGPWjUo8vlCB/EgMAZKWL4UglT41iZs@9kjGU9G80WOd4WxCDBhkPXy5y/MeL2gtWuxpm@fUXgppjth8Xt5ibdwQZ2hGG1@k/QQBvlCR7WSJPQmXcksZsfK2esndFC9su3@a@cTWYRyMjG26VPpdWUwg1tw24RZ72q9FG3LL9YrKhvH1itVUdtL2W2WsKpdX3VE40O4K3Dom1Oe4ta8ykzCiDEjgSMz@yvQM44MCEylqYlgkWdZYtfvousyEnnZNpwF2PLk5sohQ/ClPc/vLxNx2iuwlYthBeICRik35On7YjXTUlSET@9wfniE7oN/hhGojuTfj8zzkpJ3AuN@JkfYYMpucJ/OZupIbDP3zS99Vuf3@8dAfN2jZIs1n1PIc6iFCMAEJTD7d9KzuGYSlR3pImCJxV9hyCMkLumOdHk3GNhv7nGBIzVTQYVcwCVLsxJQMvqTGaoKOCVd/xyDYKE8J7/g2UotYlrywNNKQsrbbDE@zqamTMS3YcyeeONmMoBrPTMMLutIVFtpLvvglSd5FjADddlZ7AWpXhDXODYzV6Tzo@anFadDNGEf/4oaSdRHzmVNRijVSRkN5Wk4y3gEr0iN/SkeBkLXJhDPKLOTzCx8jnc4tZ68jHOQ7tsUv@iqME9BxAjP2DFFve6EIy4kVKsmB4akGW/4ThE7XPyf8xjf@GKz4MZd//qDonPz0sXf6KP@x9@Xjbw5jokWyWWULKqcvs43E0nOFVsaim/pprNIiE2rwYy9d4GNPiQ@LRQJCpJg/@al4@qVICH3MOc6j4secECQ1ZMCkOL@9IsAXp9DMpbEo5jILziPHDH7@edlRtLbyX4yhvHDkL2FhNpV8TE/7nGGHQLGf7q9X4nISFddXSk9Wyk9oJ3Qe3BaGwRXW20J0dRbckioRYTtLS8/H31LckCLE19vI36CXt9RPSWsivieRdlLSIlRPc24nE7MV1fGEJ6g8UZnDpcLFxYnL@Lh8xIbfVcRypizHghLTQYv78lg/o/4l2vEjyLVJ7xDhSFgZiI0IH6EWANkkX7mLQx0zXZbYz8lT24jdykBoeIs5a7Xo9XsFraw53tIGlGh4zXTXS@ulyTk6NUVTM3RRK1NLD1R58/nT//jvB7/mRrnNleL7If0d5X7Nra3n5JEe6Ndj8@s6t5l7hmJrX3PjIu2B6fHpf/xPqr/5F4KDL@Nn9M/mqoG1Ns5tFqpc5Utuc40eyisr1O7/@td/pT4syo4NuVgXm65ixDYMRbb9HvMufVcN9FK2pUuJWGHHLMAQC0Pam9MPGEbdrqyX@Jgup60qrgMd@crYo@glng2zRmwqJCcZxp6CNCOpUEUDBQFpTCg6yrLdMGYbYN4ETfXzQ28toh3Az9qcI24yNt14GMFkaFG2RTSAeWmR9vPysFl6no3NOypZY1OyYVRIbO20rF1/vEHs8KYfjMJW2krCTNfLln8TnHngQy9oX9Geqhd1@78Mi9fEkpfllfViB4f7RbbjLg4YUmEw9n4jRVAnA6KNIRudumpII9C/RAgvl7MFkUK/G99JmXySpGUPgpacYaVzElMR8fFz5XoY3fESVTrP/5ICj8yZOhGklSvtY49qHhxWVHY5LijleM/rAJs3bByrQ2AUxBp2wLLJy3AfcDpo@uPVhufshMS1EHVdinh@u9309bd8ZiFrUqW5mYWLoDuoZjsS3h2xU3FjoukvauadUAohThAKBRZ0gHUZjHzaolez/Ab78aQFhEnRd61xqLiErB1dVu/q21XOujKn6Rtp@oZGFFpC0k7MM1Y0NmUXE9lSxVHlMGjiSm1mw9RaZJI2Dz3@AwwiGZZGB24JujvsAUlUS7qjrcrsYXN5L0w8chOIz54cLUrm6kwucX50TQnxoIbuhHY9aYwEBKLgVmChTL@PxAOiatKMhr2MxPOb@Gzie2gw3IcDhBK1w9ZJ8FFZlnrXyH0TjtiXUhEJdFxZ2wY7I6tHDDoOsRWnoM3i4CXrgKU6Fd5scUEzHBVOA21CQmWzck510lJxetmOzl4riSLoRbZUXnn8ZHXt6fqPyHK2oHs7GwwqedgFDC58gsEadZ422XhfrWaXsvIKKainmwT0WWBxAQezrhvHMWGfb5wH1XJJAytlGdYNp9GQ6vq4kkEmEIeBhxWB9ij5YTaff145QcdOP7adL/Qf8beJD8gMZ8LR@kJ6axzeJJGpMpcScKDKgpmD4uQfI4KKo7/YZYN@5xDRJgLYugrbU0N7iAAxuhj2r84vbO7wdGirY5owRHCOS40d1MtglAQYs7CCLqoPHBqW90XVwDuZ7gGMcrEkQOcT4DTNdNxKX1uaYnYs0SKEyJrwWMUVomU6arMzc2evr@r7O5OI5ew0dAzXsy1bSbnjSGYIIINcvVZ3j4m6OtoFu5JqmeSmoiqzgCuhXJnd4X34SreQiNqiipHVrDeM8vPIUmZeTEKbJlVpHIHXDJjl0rdJafxaTS9AECMI9WlSLMTc@D7HJlmCkz3ImKfg5WzFshF9HUYRB5jTjWUdbVHKhTirwELmDoA4tyllpSOlCkaUH@uceFlGG8kcxSsaRwPaDDneqQYzS3KaCba6jSQANrKOG1qg/439bVft1Omf3fc7LhTlrdpf0e84xfPd@JY1vuWKauyaIbCjxbLNLWymfoWLEjFLSQeMTRCE8O1IVsQgiRpQb@xq2sukPknN7dOEK8CuvlbCzemoniQI9MJnIAt68x6H4mB3HX5XkcOraUkTh1TR00KOuOZPbIsmC0mrMSQh5T1ArEyCiAO1JNy@kDC8WKCz5u3rvYth7MbubJ5OsaxsqEht3y0S2dM8eydl5rHFimaLlQrGcR5fMN/O5Y2zoNPXvmgxc3yDNx78Md4o3J85Cv9fMEf9n8MdjzV3PK5A9gh3xGHD2aOT07D3Z3DM2ZjX4GY7PA9xPtSxfqITJdcCwAIPGMKHlD6WS@jbHeJE5Wd/WJ5cj2AktLIKx4A/1PknuvNPKpC5/LgT/L/a@cI/uPOruvOrFaw1M0Zeq3ZWuPV/TI8TlTCffjFzeKHuSjHnj/Z0Tfd0rYLVdMYw/1/vaeH/UE@f6p4@rSBiglw4SPj6@dwsmkjtaLvRSMwtvIwO2pVHHvvZXOlg79WuZmnz0OleRRdVaOvqD@O/rvFfhzTiJ6Shw11EbBsa7@VleyrO8qJZ8imHgpOV9ET6ayKjW/3VC1ayH9ELlAhpPtga6o0KKeSufExum7xEf0ykb7z43Bdnke06WSYuzq0NtOwIy04yxUXz1UkyV9bidWWHYyCr7ePDveX/ImS49D9pLzRCHkN7E3S7ZiWxt2DHcdQp3RmrO4B9pPccKVbR5GRkR9rbO2aXhbulGge2mFgXZ28S5KoN93@0l7qEvmFl5caREdHG0/XNrgqmuWZ7IW@o71Jodpd1j/8Ql/6oufTHijrUG4O7SOXrAz/Ni8k@bWV1dd4aILU8/MEELLlUfs6s@t8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/vughl)

mycon is separated from Clostridium by checking the cell size with [`2y`](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#system-information-retrieval).
In Clostridium cell size is infinite, `2y` returns `-1`. In mycon cell size is `4`.

```
@,,,"375"< >"863",,,@

         ^_^#+1y2    < IP
```

Answer (score 1):

## 376. Befunge-98 ([bff](https://github.com/zehanort/bff)), 16385 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#8""C""Hata>;re^;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML4ot5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@  @,,,"375"< >"863",,,@9
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC    ""                $p/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9    >"473",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@_  ^_^# +1y2^;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdtVVdUl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYk8daz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBldn/OdnXTy2tZQcBYe@5gOjLsiVcRYkxlzNLtwVQfGKxvWhPDTTPPMFjHsJxzCNcY257aU8/o1eEty5htnLNDu2v2AAKbOKeGbb4xXAjLMfbAsC5HlxPWdUYj3e55bOya9oRC84w91eGlP@2eMr3jTVy9OzEdG4IKjD23LX3U6emMoo9dgycqMgDVPaU0yyElxp44rmdADk7X8DwHPcvgqbum83jv04@vxVcz7GMdkBpbxuxa9qrKPjcNt3c9hcY@O3n48Lpvln1Ncmz28CZKao7tTSfO4eQ6/DzbGxi2zjS5LGvXAwtAzIlhlTKlzPWgItSnMTG7S/lAwEPThdrV/VpkXd2G2sK63GLGaDyZM4nXv25ZYd16TPfY1JvqFsWzp6OO4QYRvYnuTkx7wM7NyZBNhqYXpqPY3ljvGlLPsMyROTF6zDIhkdP3oQBou8dOjfm540KV@zAd25pDQqNr9k1MEuABAPFKTIYGhzPS51DJ9gQaB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/gOjMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPh4btN2YAJwOIE4dj9WpKqBmLNq/3eiwD7RjwODWYCVQjtCosmwV/5rhANYgVYOQDo3bNy2jMoM6givpOheUzGQg/CH0QW93yHB@ZZdQw0Ia@SnWGcJ@6zsDVR0CNnkE0/ezwKfO6jgtv8MO4vD/dBqarT9j2NosffPogzuphtchuRwirqMYuoApiQSA7060ptJBoTThQP26YWsAqi2/EKywOZNEyLJdjOei2JablgUhqpgwO6P9aVoVfgWklllOhB@Xjacyn7@oD0zI4lAFCKWLD1/JMg3smx7JqicccOFafR@tSZkWWLbFCkRXzrAj3MitrkBuCzjG1nIdfAX4ArQyoqPDL5jigRbuHdoptbZ/19ZFpzX3oBL7L8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW8hWFPRkCtYf6GYCXLPMUuZERMiSsQgUeytaWQhwRWS7P3hti9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaCbLPZ3hBvKFhWX6yoYfJCNtiBn6AeRHoUALqZ4CWGSRmEX7wDvxOA8amARfTgDFpwEw0DdxZzALiFSCsAFVZ8Ok11L1TyIjno/WI@MDRAYyK1EYmpiKRAALUFstCnRVYDhpCFhtCPssAf8ClWGDAx0oqK@VYqciAnuUMg7pRAS9sJSrwTxXwUREY1L8KDUAFnFSgtgpA1WyeCRFiq1kMh7RZSAukUXOQJgduqDi1gD9IBy1DhSxVyFPTyotGCLhpeShvPkutUytA7RYhDOimAa4aNCcNsNVKEI5pS0DDEjbeYjzNCaEjHaBWsLlDOwRi5AEfggtxwa0Vs5x@ujUe6h3k1jxlp49JC9gNCkhGSJrB4sEzh9QEVDIABnsBoK9BC8gCObJQtdlcmL2lApAGgjd6JjFoywTepYYUKqapQb7Sx5MF2dQCYTSeT4ahn8b9HGCcJjA/Y6B352Eg9L50GLjwLWTRVyNeuwCUyaGvB5zVmXrWAkjoyGmUlXFmWgu/Evn1DL3XN73h2wWuOcqkY@gT2zxd5JLPpyNE1SMBBQxY8ipmo3EnpgTD1WCIrkVZtCLGGTthBS2hrKqEXsfoT@2BIZVLEfwoZDJ1JzCwLPIsc2/XHAxgTF7AUdNUTBooF955wtDKZidC6InUxTxdE4bve6w7BIEiDCxz@OXyAkZWQxhzvYOjugRSGIwCZRy3@uaMde51adRYIJglOnWH5jiIXFkbOVK5lMmsVIi0DaLcm1ImZM14teRXjmkn4iyeFK4EGGu4ZBkdqWFA@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@t9Y4yHAIKNeqw770L3hErG1iP0HGIw3fFyMRdvmwbEsVEp2X/682xgANlBYO2jdopNflGA8ZiKQKTQbS7M2jpQCovQHc@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@@uZy9ii96cdc3ZdC@@ip/zKE850l/VRAXdB6IBOlIj3vXiySv6UMhIkKs54olBSfhchIkWSocoTfdDpYZB4CIzmeG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ5MyGU09gmoCtexQ/UBG83oFPo1vVXZAIZvSYK7hH6ECQYoMgboLsgZ0AlByyyXex2dXQL3cJk02@eqSKCSqHIuzMuwe2FePiEQl2h5ZZ6F53bJIUVGNSwBRqeS0yCxRMD3pAQlFMFDUfyxFT1I2uNhJNdwz6lN83AswUWRJLsIhV8YABKEjAnCh9k1J21fXLl3LxBcNmo1aGwgTQHb7CWjGm0wYSkDp4bIMkkjfibyxDmeYN9IJKG8GPmKYwNiE7TUWp1dTIYu9Dh6vxIgEpBVsLElB4T16/lT83Tau17RNnpiJBF7HQhNZnciVgUY/HlvqN1G1fgSVUHrjSNVsfFiegJ9o/GSL1ao6EdzDQ/F35qPSqSGE4iB31ZXkogn9f0WDXp/3rV8kYC7oLNzbtQB9E/9iayQEaV9mSDotDd6KgeC3YHDYU/3Th7V/L7IA5WOaVeWPCynq1vkvYnRxSDt48P7z/ae/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@EH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8@jZ166TBCQhJAflAG78XRNpeBwQuoSO7g2vDcJskEpBlmGSIC6TDlkAM3Qg6hiuB/g8nb55g5V3Hamx74@YWVOdAwg8lUM7SCdj4DUBLAjq9PmISGlBCjVtXGhYuKIxA3w@Rqn5OjIkSkeazMdHDw@e1QisP68mURTFm4Aspbs9Gdq8NQUVfFUcYH/g6rKUvEAc5WnCdSWBu90lAi/qlq2BDwBQ15EdJlmjoGjeEHDfv1428pW6YQugd4JwXa6MykPdD0U0ggcOcV1UeVeNohSwGKxCr5UjVhi6PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs9eFCgtCsA4EMiNLgSdehL6yAsp0herffSPH99A3CMhElQBKcDMs5hMeXmWgNqLZLK4p@yDhuZYhvw5cTyRiUlFiQfrAnLXI@UzEv9gZk4SmSR/qkmIC7nv7R1qD4LI/pQ1zWSQ0oC6OI5Mbh/X97oetBHbsZyBw7YgDZcOgwxBbFpbzL2BY9@oIR09sagxXCIE/osTN/oYxhrzDSmOlCqqrvLFRt32zoFLq4UsEokoRKAUii@/0s90INei3MeH3ziAQUTNZzKhO0MXkCCShsiFrm7ElzyYBBnJPj4rCxguF97o7UGAFFmvw0L7jC5MuLcIXulJHFNWVsZfidInzg2Kv3Lm15oW@PCmBY4IyQ4/ffr48NODJ3tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC0A4yK8DspA85HTD3rrFuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyR2BNq@ELrYlPnKEd95LXC3OOodIru8ub0BPsfDyqnxAU7Z6FyojLV6txPMf2M5xMxl5FUaCXD6cdGZRW5VXXsfSBQulgYLAsRUXV5fAI5zW8VSkAGW9u8BR8cgtEhznNIOrWyAHlhda8kTWwBAdPs1aWORiCLowL44ablMMWTKVReqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1WtxNu1mtFyihhEW@r@EHejb4DqlIDRCkiRvPbKmvea99gcuDRCug4kxuQtmuTwGI4FFgNBkmZNUc8PiEPcAudLkVcQjV5PcTYXuJSSz@SKaiGvgFoGahrIrBLOuUkjfdIdShNHAniS06d5g0gr7Htd3e7LW74jQBbkvo@gqNnGi2bTboGA3rxHuOG6c2PeaqitZJXdTLLlx09WofUuFQ/bbuABbZec0DTpydbws55@k531dOpdPaZMRmN/zJHG7MkeCFJvHODXPSPa9zCBEg1UtpbiKhj5rbJiQsjCpALekFIKdCgYaaHpKYiXBEIviofQcoBvRRKwxWwGLwff3xHhI6h0Y7s3nbhHayQo1@BsqTcGItJkcxe5tIfzgxMYHcOWj1waKheZNDs34jiPrnt8thIS@Wv8QXrQ1UIINCsfzkjb4a4GaASUitRz4BzQrnDadLiYZUSlH1oaZEg44eQDSBA2rR4MgM9AYl6QPV4QnhP5LBfp1HbObYTWMVhJ6pgTPtnvTF1c6zZ70bJB9KzG4wA0KlyEr9OieMfo8llWnphKAUqgzkbGyMGpBJCuiBUYVASdL6ijLujhjDV0q4yEK4YAX2K7@8DFugafL5JGqERBkzpg8Ymr7EnfUHTpDbTmW2QrLHykiv1KPwkIsLy9gWZJ/BlQkk6cEUX6nOZbMPB@IO4KuGIIJYYWJuo1Z2zY13U@rhEmklXahhCP80Wgi/jGxka8Eq/H0@DaAdc2unbQlQLXDrkkcmE8GV2UIk0uDG1QCvRrxa8aAeRZsoVtYIaSwxtznNAblUq2ldYbqv/U8JmEqgDKQ2wJHwAnnqzV0JlMivVzXLMB@T1S9n1sO8dd1xz7JPgEBAL@7tMgS0QA9R6ledeoom56O0VGNReURgNFzIQbbzYyzVbzotlLNa/iaUydrOo10A@BeU0SI3ngOtMxCG6NXEUC3pZsZCutaqcWz8S3EomSZEFGejL5USmZ0jmtE3ED2lSi2YwDSX3qNLpDl@DN0loyGRIK8OiboGVYViIuX5Qg/06ylUzFIW0ynga2XIvHgS604OhRoXFGgDeih@YMSAkdE4a46JoCMUhanMLu@g1jPJy70QjhrBtI2TiDvtirglt6kItHueQbnj4q0C1p@oHcy@OBcIuTdygvjeecuwsc06aytDMqGHfPpP7ImejKZzIoTXJkuIxvxBVJgpGQQjgkKvYT08MurNuGM/WiM40rJ0Axd/A9GU6BWQbb09LQqsyxYHSHDotv7gJ0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16UOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8aDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSR5ZvQEC/hHH9ijzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hBECSoOcWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEjjgRgO5dgdC5znraZpW6Ob7lSAMWwUQewiVhFqpDSpuECSpEJj0K/mATwsFOvqnRw8O@NwJDbY4vOI8Wnvk9KYgV/p60zPDHqTZAbQn03ZGJpAhSP/m1HrmOBOu5cPLupkZrjSbo6ml05zP9WmZW9N1nY5j0VTQbUkX8aeup1s6n4QKQvc@ewKy/vOT45pciURS9LPRrXnjPOTqbDk9D6NrjrTeGiwPebxhipt5EcetYNcnshk/oIABU3/PJ9RR4F9E/6BL4RqK719C/xHu9wRZ2Z9FoNfQ049Ypoi4BxQ3vPmeF2rmCv3X6mBhPJXiccFxge2FqpH/2aTfX/LOkvephKzJWnjnyJvvBV3SEaMo5Xkk3Bi6FCcKqEBxwv2ha@MVKR7f3SKHK4tPwk0IQ8MKlhafgcSCy2cw6FsoV4HSgiI638NpgIQ9xlUSYt249sa6IIR6N@YzoLONJR5biG1QB4LBTUGRRthUmD/3XaUuZDv@mqXH2aoDOj9Nq2zX@So36lQuV@cUPiu/2QYQ2/VqsOFuXTTMKR4PoxFUwg1SUDFpYf9GUcNtGh5NtguUpCp4CqgTMy0jNWfFg9ZlXPGIDH0mNpuzjzLaF6CX4G7JzXvKwKjSHqc19KoGIXFfhu3MmQQSH8biE9fdIfAZlpotkxLqZ2r3Hasn8VUyaDCM61dYQf4mhXAXp79Z1zDdYAMn7aDlSZG/RvZ@3oB7rUrrNyNEdouGgKD7XLDL0/TZJWvAkHcme2PLnLTYlTxx2kN/p5R9fV8pl0FdV597gr/Hpcb2nn38WSPT4hCEkY4rXyVei7NgezIIziAo4T5ycOFOnYk5IUmAdiKYWF5VBqRmtEgC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULUL43LRVn6BmiqCQMx9@ajNDOSV3Lf0icTw@Ztji8/ric3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8MAxSo7Pnlw8OyZDC3XS8QPcAWnAt1R7w5BQFlX6ICS0cJX2Ee9OPsI0yRRbRegq4H20fbTQ6OuQqMH/QNyR94xMNwEeCZx8aUL3rTeRQm5hOYTCPdbdSdEoxBYwkhCmQhYZSX@z22uavl4VqDFp4iSQO7EvQrQ1kzKU9t8LXsw0JDcClHiXFmF8aK2mSAutqkm/Q11I1w6Bg2LhEYoQaPBpDfA5SCyyFqtKt8DAHFRAXMHSF1RpKqgXew1Naj6GniDSEMQ/OS1t@xFIyOVW6nNVaBoc5m/AZ2XPwIXISyD9oyV2W4mqL/f6MgcB74WyDn3c1Knr52@qLBN7hD5nDNFDzZMEdOh/VXL@6SWd2FBJ0NWQlMxWJCAJcT84wF@m6Vw4vyg82Ay8kgk2UVIdA1Jzi4viYZsU2NEQ3CpjFfGVaB9AmN67EBpHvtHA6LSAfVWfyMJ9tmmIAZq1vJKLYZwEV45uyadSmdiNB2XDk371KH1ntDVzshqHiXCMPXo1LqZEjeh0m0paogDj6utw84bdfp0WxGBlj38BXXyoAl1XxYGIVJXntGD5tZX5Ly8iWQpW397Ko204GbS6ztiSuUSRe53Oua6qEAE3BcWPFdEAyaF7VmTc7IanDXAqRgYj4Bxce1lUfTr@4/YEt39fbT@8z9/swf0v1k7QxgocOYxdLRh6MaakvprK8tPii90W12xfIJ8apk6EYZcd4Hs6i4USbdCx2rQtAgvSTD8j3BJwa9xaJt4A6nxlmbGMecrgsFzdSarFtVsYJnddXGv7cfiWdHyDyh2PSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYMz4EkxExUY2djdSwaYpRo2Z1/twOpnyOwiud1aiOcbfbX3Tj5nJ6x3VUPjO9Vuq3NVPpz1HGp8OQjm1sCLuovS0BiyBOOAvB7fRubr4vIB8J3jwXBdtMbQp5/S4q1V49tQbSx3Swnv8jTrC6JYcXIvf10Ux/cN7oWM91UyLbu/ZEn3o0FD83RAK7jWVIkQzr5HZ0jtzlEGGH97Kwp0FwHFq3VQqk12ztDwer0@PmiSlL5dXp57JXU6PVXMECt/PKvFZNCqwv8P1jlqF4coc6Zak9SLOtcx81caEG1HDNU1Kg4cv6ATGrY0cB6Tu1NLdheuWJr7AI1hGWDcj7Q8bT82uA@LAmKlFWdWCoSMyYBDLDLbGLTLC7cR0i2x/MFeRMThOIoWu1SzA6U5wy@iaNvUeDI1v1cQNsZFGIjvrKNV1zvG3VnwYgmrK76tHtDcrsXoP5iRZXUuHcXztcLA0OYiTj3c01HPTM@i2mrCnKxGddK2V/stdIJj2i07j3dWsPdNyPHZM99sINHCBCvy@ukFHaWnqtkST4VH3LTwo2OOwqFDdGjhWoTRQdLitrfWp20e@7z/fl8OFHEpV7@BQgfjj2Kr/XMvXTxX39K4KogOLLu5vjThvGWJXsSl/7WV96UAxwIW71SV7mClRSlnhU31rMsYll3N9Hjx/hqFjHWmDoWM8J3EapDtMUC6BY@JyEftnyS13e26992NKN8AW7ypEpHJPLQMGK7rfqFKmZdQPTKFmMu/PovrW1JgaKxWNo84rA4/V36JkvD9SGb8Ym/5MPS4O4NGUMNYbXzN8L6xxnMa3W5mJbpld425RZpmpjUH6HqPq/BQcT9FxM8XAno6XanVJO7Of3U6y4Tjo0k5vCTsM@VA@VLpDUlqSzz2DfrdqTFzDww1itXwmk/EFmMiKy9LLbZpUNkz7yuT3pYzJZ5HzIi6usrkR5@o8iCzRLYhrWZC2TrGnyOWyYpu2MZnj/T25acdxrA@pKWCqeGDYAW1Voq22t9XYDXHHP0TCFlMXHk54dPrrJi34aOPrlkAfVJpvq/ToktB71aaEi54jXJBafr19@iaywHRXLni4FeeE@OZba70s6c@GqHJJLt7a67iE6nQMS@ePWSF3G7yynL0V3jLT8BdrcXGXL@kuluJj15jSeA7EMnugpQyNkUGvt0j5eg9NZPiPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vMDozuughjE/iCjfelNeSIsDRxbNCvJrjPD/UUC3eS@r7rOHCw6reSyIcjfWBwmy23ccrFhAXupuFq3cK5euqiwnfQdCHZwhjH@iYBnerUmHvBcyXAJ/Mu1Ot0dPd027XO38U50Pfo7eu2sN4cYu2hM7SHxpDvGw/f1nUOaI8TbmPnNtQB68EQt7KNx0tb3KP0tBzLeh96ImvkjNJx@itxOsDDr3hy64Pg8pP2/uPOyTt9wnkHOtb2mqExhXHJcybO2JDobV1UCyd6@H0dDw0WqX/WGaRb9XygSPD8WeHfqVsOdGcyHtOjPbamHt0oqURnlu@Sm/p8awptinTcgfzGGXVk31P2963QEvhqFtMxJ90hHhrnLdsYOJ3u0LwLad9QhRJM@fDX99JdkTImkx6gt2yZQF53LmN7qUXDj/FxuK7S/dkjPqyFjlvklVUzdHQsWxrrp12Pz4aii1VwQjjSG/nh7Qodf6@8npqTBdDIXqZwepcvS6BjHe7@7om1khWdkViwYX9XxdpWSkI6CuSSkQGBR12X7fI@t0gXy2b5bR1C0VISRpF9KR9Cbn/vD80OmpF5W/Bfal9Lm5ZWDnL2cDrwbjJMPl3fAxENb@unLWgvc2TKGsYs3fYf68isWQoecoRnG2SuqXHrmkr@1kUViqdaku6Y8GjDA6puunYOzTLHHr8zqb92Kc7fywS6@PX1Qk6b@Wpl2q@YntHnSyDouktEHDku7kQGGUTq4ko6zqAjM@eCF2dctjMApi5ZbBE5iLtObFm5TWh19YdjpvTFp8ZAx73Wj80JbtZc0Sqoya7aXnQn7K9Pdc/8@hRKtq6xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeE/0gdl9tFQRIZI@gf2dnvyx1PzR62ZdnA9ND3c0hY5bJqawyfFGjK2uDXrDipjX5@1DYxWLDsSPQa6MvWpu3RnP8bTYnFy3TaubE5pl9Z/rVMd1m8BuReJ8OhpPPf@xGgfaMxWdhR6dkr93bgJw6TWwVjbUrcnqmerIlCtIYf6guHCuk8a/YVrOgH2jlGEgtIEQhsL5ioZzH4bnp7ghx7VXtETK@z2XPXGiQ3J5wV5D3RpZJpm2Obl9Nmcywc05wRMLw0cOPKGgPMa7vPuhEKST1RR5fLesvziafMf4Di3v2Jm6XQOdob2RqFrg52rsB7uP8USHg/ZSzqNaWtexoHuBw1rZZbqOPZ1I7tS@dVQo3DoqVNDaVKQZsMTXD548T0ZbA@3WvksKDeyRLVxrNwxca2SmDYLYej66HDvQJR5wO0nPaKvwHWn20JhTl9j1A2eVvvN0DgPIeytMwPynowdGF5cN78z7U@eJYzswGo2BUY6eGfzM/9JGj9UJMdljPNUO9Ondmc0xgV0zCHFpQx8bHahfa@F6n7GIA36gT/Q1QxHNDZL@F7rubCum1THcVzTpF3GvU2mXEXpkzEi3WN9geB@UJt0uF4lxPm6pjyyt2Hhjx7H5nbhtBh7qk9u5CgwFdHv/hXIZN@IvzQus1M@Wi3p0xneJGD1ulGJdWV2j41j8fsueJNvkewJ01zQ85THaOCC/Qo5JIH15t/KQ4q08ZKEagSR7pnu0SL9a1ViAVGcfsAVoqLtdB1fCfMctu3MihgnuYNPh3n6@caADhJ8Bx9K7U99Y6F1oWaPOiG5rFYZIbT4zOngqqEPWPCb67GZl8pkh35RBZEdXaAAgYFfYqQss8RS0keTdw9aSHrVMVXNMN@LUa5fLabOOZJtG942Os2YO0WsxN70UDmVWPiXnmrnqSDeiWWRFp5PuK3vS8tY1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclt09uBmZUV6yHTkYGLzMurMGtFV8cbUmGd1evpIXN1Dcm39Qe8JLT7x@VDaW@t5Ing4f/o/icKDMLtQi4wPQKs6@4VfEB@6tr@431a4FPHm/TN2RHgjacA1rETLFYeksCD9wx0ba0rBNSePbX47MMgsu9q1CN1TCIrzJJkEbueGJJhn0lkCG52s0QOP/Sl7KH13onRk3w7CLjSID0Ozn@F0fznigXUKG/EzZ6qwgk7K@T87Z@riHsecAaQt5yJNPboqYy9p4ePj07ksaeuHJ/2hng64oYct2RYQStlIlNSr3Q3st7Jt6P1TG@i3D9Wpf3HhzJGWENvvqIhwQNX5pYea@c9Ayuuir5WC8JQY7JaQHx08uRxanFEkyX2h64zMpLR4P3j4zSeNPnkeGVwNPVD6B19Z7Y2@eGBqiZXNN/nNq0OruOeK3JaB@nEAG0UGuMjbpflTuGq64yN3sl8bHwGgydycO89sy@sLeSn@pk5wF7IymsJRR2VleVCLhnZmQ3KtuGGz3X1eWqOkVt26aHwx9rtKCg5ZBU3u1p6uG3F/7oUwzL@ToQPS6RmbrbWqB1hRff@voipqrqOzsd6H@qV5ddW1nKEVevDlnP2HkvJhq@8SKGXNIFWJZl37iMvSiNg3QrecHre9wRnZ@02mNsAhN6FlR3@3LDnui3RWtZt4kUFUuOmtlujfMN4jwWpcIfPGRorX7nGF26pZ4kuOZN3ZHziRpLs798/vCvBM5@Wt8f6@NPn7KnuoRGS2yNGMTbeA@OFZPRKwnkrtIC3djm15wIo7VZ4g/Hq/lxhx7rbc@z57O5FODqDikM7GRcOYeEbRTIsc2auGqu6fF7r6eptRnflzQ9xOPMlOThqnMYH9O7b/0xVMxkyPYRPNcNf76iZoIOzBLr0OdqziwadHIasoYtyiwweyZXa6GNjhttR@GzwKqV@5fhWuGXsKybXDye3hZVuCcvdkt@NMPRkWTmj3gIwf0sYy8th8GPHOh868r7uGt6K/ccrEbqtIOVbClKOcGffWjotLPru9SI@Hl3wHytb64kxcXPjodMxcyvLsNdHI5PsCRpLvxnub6fQXdreMnD8Ix/8fXV@51NjZUZP9DerA4jTnK4MAiZoDKd0JOJm8PICaQdkXsMemNy@IrvvTA7o7RbFLDzxvHovgjl@MB2vxxh4I36S4jo7X4r4OejMzrnH7uPRuIWYvkL3x/1xq/3XybQsnBhEM6OPTvaC1nV0rGiRHBdYfPF0yRsPj06OjiN@rjGbrVN6pdk6HXJlyCLXT09yS9lu11@crSDW@vNGIG4APw6fa@Ugzuw@Ob7JElB9G05GVhDyiW4vZkyXKqznTOik4crAp/MZbaNcWdNDvottVZjbXeG9pNjDgGyakLentNtoWb/dXtcqT4wvaO0BxCA24WIJB@obXjJmuWGAISVZ21Gd04Xws4Tu8Xho2rOVQaN1aWgXaeKVt7ob7LFjyzlnj0OrQuvYg7YauH5m2OuY06rDilI5e7sUlr0mUq2rF/71Ev@xrkrurxPUrvEM3BBxGzfB9M@6ysPg5TMteWf8T46D6HfH3bccnL/vmdPR3ZEJbCp1d0T3FvZ3HaB5dzT82Mfp0HHtu6MGzalSuW@8JxIb7x1zNO8674FDp99fEYkfaoY@ETWI76V9k0bcCAA/eu3JwVcLEgkbyJ1c/kRU9Bw5mo1ObKLZ1E06Mw5xLy/Zhn9OGwLE4OS3fzIdrSua9tTAo@X8wzGT2iZkU6up@TLbwW8yVUArTFKO6EU27IK8Gmzzwj90XamoV2yjxsSKyPxj76FJam5WGeCiQVgoE5NOVbY5gZDN4Mg2oy@EsEtGM02g2qr5DLzJStR4RdU/1A4obV48PXx6cHyyd/L8uJFpXfmH3oNC2DbkFpjW@CjbE6HsPtlAguVG1snYggXZ0ddLcIbKC8rF8ItIy0WrLRVtUShxB9NsXti2otC5f0W6AvwkkedGociHwYvDDkpM9eObfKjwI/hkSQCqiIMWKU@oswrLrMp4rIM0tmn74dc/IEah@IG5Cn5iDjP27WJDQxw4Ts/P0TPY3VeQ48O9w8fPnx2wAMFFozk3e5NhrZznZtO5LRKop75JGyFrLO4niUNd1Wrxh3EgTFyOswpZaiCT5dDOIVpAHbTx4KfeYolNgg8UjIeVovznbypXcRn39CchbjxAKg7ZQpOnhrKxscFOoJGwB88OPzt4xhD/gwfkjSRCEOwEj4n/2Y96/KMfgRmn4ON67ohEJzKDI0RNRQT2ExYmHpDm1HXH6z@xRx/ZIEMK4dc9ws8TCQJ9/AXa7TlZYLxmnS9JBrP4JwF944lBRtSEgg8F4PIRGkJ0PXZmeiaacUAc@miXcLmx444zssUpsz38fiB@pVCnL9AA6lN7wm1/@RaAYtDS5JDlpNkmIcu/VyNGIsa3N6CxdwyQqplnmyCjTSrsFbREXKKpcDMfklSP30gSgK6QS0JJLBLxhiFDT2m6yrtf/SfKoMrAPQH3d3z3LHMf3n7Zf@uD@1e4@4WCDe2m4cMFLlGE0FipXwKOSEh/pH3ks4k2N62yIBzaZwz4KjNHUE1nRHWMznPgdwnY8QJOovEZVBo0N6gx36QKz89wWwm0llpRFGxSqOnJdKDFmPHdpdesphbyhZyqAJLSWQCQPnMwwGPzHGAyWYFuIpyZ49pL0B62t7eZiNM9Rq1Q5TWrbNovsuLLENFNiCucDxG5BoM0kGSRAsLqfjIYfFJqEpMi94qrcWRcPQdGJQrH0QvfbZ8QIksAsTiNDLSbP8MvbE5ACPKt/3bwm5SRT@Bs@oAkFcYkciVFwTdG8qkzgeYDnXTxkStujAR3V/MREM1qevy7s2R0F9ujfLNnLc7QB9/a8fuajDyAg8pmrg@m0boVP0cQxwiiIq5qvo0XrDlp2i2Ft00GzfSHKxqzDe5fUgZr2iwv995Nk6uJ6wZTkVhs99h2cF7rIRSGJTRFyypqIbkoUi63skh@ifxsoDho1@kSsgM2BSyja5ivnLG3t39w@MnR0@MbZkUpZvx6NOD79e1UU5LTjVboiEeLtVwl9x8qx0/uPwwqYoF0IcKNgfH7JVFvK8liuhpBLo4/XS/aKgyvl249xp9zAwnX8c1qt6FGiW7goWY@IF86giA9pIOE1zPXSquolc/fhtICnhIBvc9Pgd9ANZG8uGq0tutNOxa/2RJWdIQXMXkLOwG4mt7WpoKN/WbhsGDhF6FP8Ft7XrQvZlf3RXEzi1br0AjFxDld2PXzPSIBkfIG2QCLFGQliLq29x1xGX1hfVLjX6zm5u6ixrwiCBcyt1E8Auok@Pg1cpGF7VzfbOxQ94aW2RECI2rcfGxg5TK0HMsNoCWSgv8FFp5xwv8c9qwyk2m/YSKJ3I5gpdltlmgDeEkBOjRKd0@noPI/dcbcIj/tK3lgBK5nDrDfB1M@D2WwT6YjiNenxzOD1viAc0uQGCgZD1HlshRwCd8Q7SyFpn4hvwaao/ULLo96@cQsKQ@NWc8cAG9PJNPA0T5S1RYLjdViock4rR0Xqc4WtXBrV/wYz/ZHyf5BFotnCwT0hi6bds@YJeLn8WSlBfmjf/z887N4UlzVlshysm9KuHfdhHKIflG9nZPoE793BvaJV3GLcvkmlwC/64C5Kb/gc2Dlsjz0BPq8Yw0l9@OJ@xicIEYk@iN9zBJTm5tBlBm9JpoJO0324aQ6N7Fqs1SKFCp4UIDMKGWfXHz8Tuj2nCWUGn4BFHw9u4ePN@aYNVRZboGbMkmyTfxM3z5IXGgYNCmADgxJKgS2hk0I1AzAiHcSmTdwSIPhEBceZExyRTB9tYyWQhykCZWa1e@xyGcXlyVHsVyu@BW6zBXLDFrfTXYoKwD2Bp8L5Hqgrm8hCWgG6q8sxBaM/CbHi1G@MY7II9@0EqATi5hFDiwuMYC1MFrcHbr4SxzY0FdAPqhUnp88bJeSishCE00D1@zhUh237B@qeP63mKCbKktR41Wu0X2MydAYZpvbgEKbjA@pw4jXWGosSgbfoHCgLHuLtqmqt7Z6P6FfCxAzhwOAf5S1HYBDA6bBHN6KsNXM/qc/jaGwkdhU1dO2e5aK5zNVuKnVPMuzjzabkrTZyNR2N3XQoiavZ03QyZWt3IMzY9jvHQ6UpiiyLMspytbFxUX84dZT80WeFaSeqRVez@ZX2UL29ewqq5Zen47VQkN@PWuJpVr6tMWePv3ibfttUpydzV@LzYQW2z@6FNUcqvyxSpld7BSysdMyqJ@QL2On7A1cp32G/@R@04u4dXR3@qDCxkUWazaB4qpYFBWlEW/BP6n7L@Hiin@jLtflndbbt8mGrk9mc2aa5tjr9eDnDEGC1JLHDPTle8DpeQKFNelJGhReo1n/5nxCnrHZnjEYTA/0uoannOXddnVuTh9Onnzj8@B6jtebZ5Fkb/zvAqdSCUlqrJinqLT1fAy/MPxnP964Sl88bW//2bdGirGBjyN8fOfqCbqP1fxHGxsf3b@fy6U1TePup994@vN7e3u5B@n800Z@JydlNrb/9E82NjRtW1M2Wp6ntuKN09MvRC2TE@U/@514@@nTr3tePft/fvNtXcVbEW5nrAh8Aq4sU8GJ9xL8VJSx3veKvYlBK1djc/prxwL/iw2m1neK/@V7R69jk1hdUz534TmJvY4VSjHuBAe8ZYO3s1g9to3RClexuVKr1cBZ/C//FtLXPwE4GDLfhls9H8AqzGN1qUZJLmP1AjhUTYN8/@9vfjOCIWcTNRLjgmuXNeASc0VN3GnBtUXXtoCmL6WMogTx7MlwYjhMLd1T7@GLCS/wsA38hoAxacbwG@vsaJexZ41UKtWS2xJc8guaJFJUVWuq6j1gB9JHW7WatMW4cc9sNn8PDZQnaUpr4MCIadz7/B/iiq3yrP7M4J4JscLG7ssH9TqUKVvPbtVTdPkdifpUsSQ6zq7I0uxlHFSQRuvlY8YtEtfFTEkT0@n0bpveZ0graRa2JLz4PRYLfbDLsut@S0kgiu8b@/B4sQO8/vx/@/Pv//n36O/79PsPaBvU7pl9ZQsinUGXqMO1W6l063Wx7ooXTXyvQzvKVEqVktK@aia2gAO1njE18/FlPJ@NH/Pvn6uMNZOUGi7Ktu5nj@/12MK7zn3qUT8/gEcmD@aXghxLVCN3SLUb8WBo9XdRS42zektCgagmNdRCviXxVPXgKrPGLlSTqBXLYquu5bUjttue8YsNNz3mxEAzLAR09PGtL8pWD0MWb/WoV6weJKsv4nxovBBfIdZoKC2DBoTAj@1uVDZKlUJFU9r19Rc0zegrRTUM46kXO4uFF6dsbEHQWNg0r/sFVRG@sKAFsw@JB5LR@zBfqqVsQRWrvktrM7EKjUTLStqgLWZUMextOL8P1wb80T9c4SveN8jH96YoN68NVlG3tKyS/6hwoOH4escVxVWAcYJ1O53Om24HpA5d7@hdXZ3oU32mz/VJZ9qZdSbdaZdhl1me0c86eafkzBhvgLIUy@bVzdg9atRvGxvsGedCLZYKrmbqzuu5LLd9Jzkc/EmSM4sJsX@Aq65qKtuC8SkDNxDKyAk6M/6pqsBiIGhdtN5uNd5uQQetp7aJObbqko8lPOT2bislXV01wF2t@v/b9dBZpYu7oHCtq1Rq@0UdpI8X9UYKQL7wQcoSI6Byu97appAwMz83P3i7BfKLlNpubNecffrJ1EGkeM6JF5zdFgDeXkJ2dzclg2sXANQ3oT8mU6lNSdrAsbHhjxUQuVVPBaVCHBIgLVxc/Iw/UPSgF19tX9WvGttXV9vb8L9N9yv/Cb5X2zf@6bG41sRZhLeQtTQbSr2pNH1m0YJ3Wamjj6w0wVGHJ8RrZLVSq4EOuOTWf5v/cnpxD30Q5ZYMWAuxLbYVQ0uV2diWEHv57sv/BX/Nd1/@PsqLDP6MihC7wG6tbKG2WeZKJ9yY/cRmT/hlgxt/wSv6oMeTOnra/GbjgpSivJRZhc/5J9RSISnjANx2@m00fiGzlxD1Bu9jolYqiO2UOtdYbFssFInd/dyNKx6P/6OXWrkY5xM1aL3hped5TyJYLvCEyFUto0rqZZ1/oIB/S@bnVl3/6OfWXULsssyMCtCn6zFOGSEGDSmmKJIEI1Z9e4T7@3GtREK19Kz2hfR8T8J5FH1CK2FdPkdQOzyolct1vsyz@ZS6zdaDLbir8H@wAeVgzT7EbfZr3RFIwM1@Nq810Zx9TOq8xr/Hb/CPnXTx79lr/GMnb/Dv2QT/2JMO/p28xr@9Dv6djPDv/mv8e/IG/54P8K/5lWxWrYqbF0SalFpWrzZnIpGoGtupN78ycecVy7AbZq/lf6kpmyuzZKz5FWPWNcaTCvfsx3/y3W99K16rxaU4ff8mpzouU5NVoD6UyItXd@NCrMY21U01Y2W6GbWjdsBhsozLMsPMUO2BotJWWcZgmXlmzjIjR@2By4C/DLjMTJ9lBixjZ2yICKHgmrQzE3T14TGAvz4AcuHPxO2qHTXTZZCRhUIbfToTwYPrst0UGizOxJcG6JqyKmfkgtnCDw41xJcvm8pWSyuXmIyNSm43XjbjLbEpohF6rZxjnbmx0XwpwtCcEXnjQx8W8zxQYKsxpdlUOJmAAkTFq6t2@@DTB@22gsNQ84lztPg/OhpFX2/9Hx05T46ckQP/R0dH0HWMemo3BQx6d7cGDNt/7MTq1Z1mhdh@wPpjyvZOs56V0F1IATfX0C/1gdcCIjzrG00hfp5A3eMc1Y/q5@fVsyq5z4NXcLSriwhBNO7wn3CdwxAXqCPncJ2do4Pe0Hn@eTN0cYfy@Tl4fc5A7wr/QcGLvv5X@Df/2/p/8pwlWaLRSiYurrYTdCXxL5m8uLq48u/1ZCLhvyS24Q894B2TXFzV0UmRLsDVSCRbyasr7gf3RHKbA6xDNtt1SruIB8NCLMySsuW3xH/dJ2TtX814FeRerlvnM9SPYmKV6Yt9Nc3mLJNJVjvB9zVwlVi/pM0LySp9XHGz01Bbf/o79A2VnSRFyueqVXWL8Rctp1WrueCtWKpWS8HLZiJRvnnVMztqAfSPXC6ZrFbhZScAm4FXSNtgb1Osxppwb927xzMpaZeXAcxsrpDKqBlMHeSUh2wNT@/6DPfi8Ig@PwKsJh/D7/5wVpLI0MeL8AN5cbEi3ruX6Bm4J7q3s5e8d08rZy4vQ5/xGLzUJa92u2e67Tb6Zy8vxbZI@2DKeXjPlC4v1Uw5pcaTjpv4FL@sCFklJJV9pNUp1zKwcS1XhGAfgfz2diFXrxdy4FMoxZO4pt5A9FuAb1yMV8XYBZVBLRU5BxSr6B3dHwR9GQcFdnEVowpluXwyAYw0CTLgVQz/XOS5fLjJ55NAmSuRx1TLZR41yXKFRClV9v9qG6CVg5DD/1BSy6ZyW8WtXZB58c@brbqQJ1cvjJp6VbswKjirflXt@t@oRhMexr172TKQqJSpNoV2@8HeyV67XRNFEQUluKEncXcBLZu48QaVPF9ucYpUqrtUzWopz6A@eRwpDiMEKwHRFW0rr5aQSILZRws9QBKBa0sbbEPQ6Ik3ocwptwGeoM5A5j24WI912AAvNkDljZnMootZjIfTvdsNIzn88kPDV0pL@l3gY4SX4PfCLG@iMIg/fby3f3CS1rYlFtMe7u2ntePn92MqvuYX7xScxfdnB3sPjp5DgqePD/aODz4@/Ozg@VPw99j54gqYvn9fPKOuFe/n7HPhlftGNwzdmBpG@3w6PX/NXplm24TKtKZQKGfgMs9oQ1nG@qJcVfh1TU9/9Up3x3Sxdz/89rsf/nfvfvu773772@9@@/s/@fL734bfj@D3Xf787r8p5/H@ky//2e@@@63fBs//AL8/gt@Pf/Llr3@T/@j9j@H3nyJ@f@z/IvH4TwBYv/yTL7/3Oz/58ld@AL9/6f9@cPP3qz9e/fv@L6z/Ybrv/e7tcb77b@H3exxWEPe7v8X98Hkj/m/xeL/yg3f/4t/x/z/1/9D52@/@xR/jzX/5pz/40//07lv/XtNKf/qv3/3C9979wrfe/cJ33v3CP9be/fq/VjPR2@@@@/4f/NUf/t5f/eH/SP8/ovvvvc//ux/807/4X//if/@LP/R/P4bfvwPXj//i30NX@ds/@CH@f@8P/vaPfoj///O/@ts/@LW//eX/iRy/wR3/z7/8N/z@17/6H//mN7/zVz/@5t/82o//5jf@4K/@j1/5v379P/71f//7f/1PvoWev/Hjv/qjX/7Lb337L3/hn//lt75cc//2rfcv38P/y38An/fH833gvE@5PtTny58Jn78PNRa5QDuB1v1L7379F6GB/wvG3n37R3j4DX5r/n@kqRTnR/zt/wMO7WaZMSQDLvj92rtvfxdJ9D8AieA/pNd3wpelEP7yncULkPU3VyT6pZ98@c9/h95iRqVOqzY4dpe0UmoL9Jutctkfv/0FHUjyi8vQQgB@Tt9BDrUU9h3kbe9@@M13v/OP3/3wN9798Jdx8JZy5fReWlLvWA2DiPn3iIcRC@8TDyN@gfmnaIpNSn0Bb@wLP/CLL74Q2pcKnrLcvQTfL8iLX4wH4SlMPygIQ388lskuWdTtOzO@c9P3DXNmrPHyZQvXW8EPc0@R7LEViEb5LJulfMRmjC/roD9Emm2Rc4Z38sXgmYC3xf/CORNYauZP98IztXCSw0/nZ8GdQh6ySc3CxSSS1RiXjra4D60TU765MsMSzGapGSjB4IAcUhB0H8TxWi2FCWscH3jlqNVLjFBJpWpQbkzN06TbJQQxu09QIGUt9Yy1t2oznjCF8OoBOVICej0TVU1MlWoPIMPa7AFDWAicwL58WauXarM6gnvL6ZGape4TTgislprV38J7jWBCOiH24C2gUqqlUvUSZoiF5NWTbvNKylPhqOwplvLrAJ643X9nl7GPRLUk8kWCDSQYj4331CI2RoToEN5MbfnFof/ASb8tIvgGZeXnwnj4DsmmO1xcxQgAV5JkWWbww/X3HbYLwTMOKkXZwiPFIaSoRVALCD0Yzg@lhBTVb4peIP9YbeuDLwSGhdnc3BRidTErHslEOkVh7mmFzj7gdkBULypMLJRF9DboIEiAC6SvUv6bcVxYizMOmH2U4r/d3S32ERSTngs/gUmprJNzYhzKdiolagC/7qSEF6CWCNBOCdClIM9qtJCXEtJpxuRaDMPY0dGRjwR5vKgJKWjmWlbFd1xOmk6nMUghy2k5nfafMj3JQ/YdMoX6T3kTiUufHmealquC9lRl6MWiqo4KKjB6vn37FmqF9ldVDkH5ZP5WKy1XokDw4MZmLGseHBjScmWBa@ZMLeQYS9AUK1xJlhRYgm0lBb4rnyMRXIm4VirFKR5QX05sBTvvCio1B5xejdUR0eDiKmEpnwwC94/Y/tGTJwefnoxbLSYY9Cl1oz12na7heQkM2/v0AT@RoZULyVijgaBPKhoyGOGgkiFmfPjg2eFxhfFC@1WQIMSqtK7qF7OsCrHx@PPtmL/zSMSvATriMd4ri7IltHIWksbqQqxroGaBC@aoAFdZVXjiDe47M9Dp06KYVguo2SVpUpkJP@9MGdqq5YZtoE/hOQ15e5soINQvJFq6QCfUVkGo1/09e0wV6scHJ5Dg5IipWkYW6l@wmYwZSldC3apZhj2YDDdx85vYzIiRMm02Mmn807JZuKu5QlrNF1sbG9aFhHk2qdoucBfjFbxeSFiMr8LFhK8K7KvgBRfkgVsTmb8v9PCo6m/OQ6twCb5DT1Tz0M2SAs5jc3DCOHpVoXUvLwQJsY1vfGPC6nXQr6XDh0IMuMWQBfvTJLMnD2Wq5t7UNSh0wFjP/MzEzzzKPdMbW/ocug5QI3Z1ddUHSIcPmVbX6JWn6OH9qks@HXBfzXQhZlcqtbdqrihop5XK26ymCeAhbCm4AW4DGgDtI9hS@F/Vg0yy2ZICnEoVRXhks1kB544FoWIIjPaKvM3UahJvg9mcSltFBPxyiD6raeHlx519tIibzfC4GAIBbDBxWSYIK/Iw/60g0BsQDXfH0Xeqq37nzNy7l8VJjGwuE85WUInZFdTNZjaXRYoL//@FB7D4as72uJ7NqNvKGJw6OHPbig7ODjjz20oHnCY4y9uKCc5pPatmtpVpXWDCNrcLy9DsTE2cGDM0Q839xLpnWH0ZzxbVRMpAE7d9O@v1IGG9V@s5XfrIfLUnm7ZtuHhInCfI5cSqY6PFwhraLqFj9SyRvBAGtXM6yi4YtYGMRnBcW7eEntxxenPZm8wtPKVjOW4tDuJgPAhYQDdADsG5r51sNldpsJY8dsY7gpYvphpqBgYQ/KmltJbeMHaKxUpP7lqG7u7kK/lSuocHgPwlrp18pjKQv3jy@NFkMn5m0KmgnVwZEqDZODTwtFOq5POtRkMUUw3KpoWfyObsSdrYgD5t6D0JnrgA5klaqQWJe6Zbq8XjO1lVk9RKNlO6EhaEQ5pjCesCJk1hydJI9wufA1RsxwZmU0nrafOCqFDp9/tXWxepxYugX0j8DehzJenpzkX4WpUi8SpsmpbMRSD46H0g94W/tlcRtXxJrDaqi/diQay2roTdkdEzdTwM1Mxc3ExVAKbMocYgoyYTriqu40wqHaPvuMYiYlYtBBE5Qjcj5MSrMLtmBnO8uJldIRJpdnETSi4vXoWpArSEqyugOyc2kN03@lunTbMNtZxrHQALguazHdgDxmixFy@E2Nazz7L1OlT1Ra6o5fK5vJYtFPJFDcabcq6QL0FnyxQyeU0DKLlyqVy8gnatKG9j9Lk/tn8RtPcKffAgoVe4xc5GiyXffmpaF6WsxPFIJKtXV7G3QuyjZ59pMECuvRIw6H6mSfVaNl8GVxZdWhYQZoKmSVpWyqqSmsX/Oxwa/r9/fA3@NbxDqqwmnKAZn09h2ISh3maP0RzIxGEnDn4QasDuG901MfaHOu1o3ncdz/t7xLmv26c86IHJbeeGQY90/CqeNzInwzUxno9HaAHIcP/BIByMOoAgskMe4T7cXMtxVkUosudP15TySWitHojBzdVD9GeHHz86iTxPDvb2HwkFdv/o0wfXHnk/Up49Pnh4Er4WeWiQNB@C@PmDx4@vv/qP3NHzZ/2p4@JPeHj0PLe4hV54YFbIwbUcKfQmIP4NX0mwBIkCFLF8MXCoAh6zuAfK8T3fmS8snBl0fs5PA5teuO2fHwyvCCfBEWGdIaftGKzLDT2htk5GGH1ZXi2WBWHMbOecFTOs51iW7jKn398Az6GOxx0NFGgtC1siZn3uuFbv3OwZG8ITPFlZVvFz6oiE8AiAjKZdMuABwgya9IVRzWa4LNWxpgabjtlaT3igFzpdczCEMfjcCSIIHV1n8PvQC9Ib0Wtyu8eE50F@N0Ksm9GFmLAbK4nivig@0id6veoaL6peplK5d0996oplcQyDsu4NjIMZtFv2HPqR7s7T4kQWHzK5HRvg2obljFEL8cYNENvLWqO1k9PqpUw@W/rr3/zR3/3Jrw1qajOzn5G2d548zjmTfAU4HAizjORVX6aVSbvRyqV8qZzVSulSuZTLq4V8Pq1qaVAMi2XQDTJqSS2U8mU1XcqVQRjJlSE0Xy76ErESiMDKVgXA2l38yvc2KUjyEDQhvhrJ3iT0JIvp4fuUiQakEQXURSd0gnzLrME4ytQMyxYZQNRZl8UePtzPPHwoivfxBXdz7GdEsYcv@VImU7wvigaF7JdQsBIdnqaE9hLFCX/JZO4DpaccAH5qQBSH@HJQwFk1UTTxZX/v4UPMp48vGqaHaKc8hL9YwUsRotn4AoI6AXgdQoNoezyfHCF6gC@YJYY85CH7ECaKHwfoYMgzHo0DeBSUdG9PFA/5y94ehuxTsfMc0a/hyx5doujCC/QAURyAY@BC3xPFDjixH4hiF1zduQ5@@EV1tEZvT3RRnHPyIIFEcUax9e6pKLYDf8zmMx@bPFK3Qi8qL/UuvZTxTxS1AGmMlg1fsqKYC19yULZHjz7Th5OeMeDX3OXPLpT00aOsbs6mBw87H3/cGQw67nzv4ONnGLS//wiEkvnU7Qw6fsJOGy4HUu0/0vTT0fz6BaU@bLcrurUy6Gvtdk63rwW1520DMYRUrwEz/xpgRqP2PgTtP2rv6qtWkwlgG1nACJ4dvO6P4Hlf7/Cg4KIges46HbGKzV9RmgkB1QZcB8bueAos1U6P9K7rVPF9VmOZNEou80Yh06pSABuB@J@pXmF4P4F3HaeAkhfzxqyWadVmtaLGtyP1E2JzpuVNMb0x2lHL@cqGvqNqudSsgkYsnH6cxSV1hyXUe1tvWOLT5I4GqoDY3NmRxIba2tHUUqVQfLE1FcVkBe872WLlTSITzzCGt2Sj2Nop5iMpisWUrmiVYhEEMqDJBMb1Ds7MtBOJc0M/TSYRW5ongCJQWdmcymlW@4lZelbjeLF5sjqrqVVuhZllbgDrocn/aXfiuBzkAMDNdjIVXIhPiGq5JAICipJIJkOmB2q7sNgJ@vnXT05PTr4gya/uT2E8dQ3kXlX/9eNH@/LhUfCGxvrlhyiQOq68j1xrKYRLpoHXCagi8iMYS0GtC/zwsKDrWPIBbaADqTYICOwFyb7hXPnk0RKc46FzznNGWwtVsr5odw2G3zIwe0yv1cGl91iCsGJ68pxG8Xa9XmvXRmSOAIoYpPoaI0P/CzCHHsc9tABByS/wAJ0f0K5lrqqd2iw2AzjtGpPUlyOn91JLdas9/ITB/dp9TFxtw7NTNWqG6zquCEq1WO3v2LWp7el946nhom2Tw6NNkCnwVF2iz4zkJmseYOx9VFiupLrL7AVmn05HCV2qd5LLXjg9F3ogcRJfDwp9QQc9cavGVbVfY4kXEPU1vLubLNGT7yd3clWg033WToJX5mX/ZZ9prJCrksKRQFjQlYg@WG6dJWv1r8GDwz6tVAAbv6JPASpmBoDNHgVA7LF5Ve3WLJaQ2IwliUi56qDWwOSXeNuWRLElSY3LllCXpM@FOvTX6jym17xph75@wzIdVcsUqjPwU4u56hCqV38xq7q18dQ1qha8@rN6/EyrXgWiAu0AzJvLxLtf/GZyW8rXuF@VQF1aIH@05XZtVrXRniY0jFq2BgGpRi6TBlUebsU0jPlaIa0W0tl0Li0V0RcG/HQ@DZ6g6oCMkbASImNiOjPLyGpaNdR0IvPS7L1Mpk8TILsQ0VgyPXEO7OmIgQ9UFbZNeoUnkCelbVmggvUcpm9L1FiBZVSxYED1IRub6SGCemboFqVIJiWW3UpYmwmMs3kyHR80WpXKwWz8dQhKSK93CqliJvUmmawmNpI1z3gt1KtCHdkLlXq8AS3Xn/Bk3nTUgFoGl1rUKo1GB4tYzKSzmSyUzmxfDrbFuthKZzYKKlTRFSO2wTjfiM4BosSz8Bu3UQS3DKg6taxVBZkm5LIlTSor@a18hk8K8pTC2GdvSEmWaIrB@e1EPF7U4vFkvIrLERuiP/8MPI34WRy4a/yeuiOCMCZWxLKGERaskY7oZgLsQBy7ElAwZDnQcC@Eq4ur7brwFeEYD15uay/wr/jiyd4R/n0FvMrwWnrx5PnR86OHAlNoxydImdWNqlxtV@FFkuu7QqzCGHDSpm9cStlg7EP3kqa26y/4s4mHCACuQDayG6xFe7wME9U39hkaLthhcSiD7o4ampZtNbQijH3ATYOomqZWcbEmhscU5DpUhncB@G2n6njm72tsPtdTUqDz32O7g9QmP1lTFrfxBFuhmKUTbMHZm2Ie/OtiqcC9ywLRMnZ99mCvtjd4thfsadvbx7t43Q4W2xwrOK29egKiDsLT6anqn/QpZtpiNcbaYt4/Uhc5DpQTt8v8vF3Ox7YpiCLuqotdxGPxK/iLxQOwL94EZ4cKAPE0s/0CmF8s9yj@LH4SP4wnY0GGWlt8wbzqqaRmtqF97NIBSo0foGSx8Aglrg/7SzvZXIEly8HKy1fiu7F4PI5LHBXmvY3FVhXxtCrGs@l4MR1X02w3XvTJWn0j5hZHB1@0X8QY7vl/UX0BGJe3qQUHp9u@9lKDzhOzncADlEic4IPBPZ/HJYWY8nLsfUMrZZ8cHtkP3IeRk1Yv6jH8TLqEh8aqlRftjVMVOk1WzJ6mY2w3RgcNxDJgonEPqIFTpgIWUBNMfP7g6ImYQ3pV1Dh4JYBqHH/ItLlxueHgGhILdza@tT/5OmPjeDYHtdGsxWa1nL9lXq3XJXVbQ5N2RVaBIbKvFqTMZZ0zgToFFDQIefeLP8jNtkvwrmVUeNe0fEqr19UtjSVj43df/j5aJ7o4@GzvMYvjysPf/cnvaMW/@5N/RZvz4le0GqFlizGIiU61UIxdXIwvLq7g4mH5WCvGkcoVk@DmK2NqrK6oWta27SqrKLq@VUzltF27qvhx1aKajHlSzN@Pmi3kpURCVQCrrWwpk4SwSz@mlinBW7Amx6OLBagoKMDBMzOvqbvbO1C@nWxOq25Ak1PDM7ss/Ns2vHJMiJWevLxkDF669d5gYGrkUhRWeSux7bfSNnuLK2JvpQ32slbHnRUqnvQNVoy28OQjrprG6yllK85ApWT1xlX1qpWiJSfQwF8YxpbdvNZqmxt49GXZa8uGP2PLoz9MFHh48Bq8GVuvPDGxlVSUXk@82Ru2DZavQ4PZUhbnkdlWsJDE/ySpmXz3i7@uaYW/@5NfvWxftr/QQC0vlwuqFvvpT7en9tQzevWfAoBbLNMEqjVJ12hCBh2hSs64VVLTTxU65K4oxKY2qh88fqCgo0rOQHQzB7bRIwVdOENxkyq3zY0j9hIUbQsNV6RJfSFjZMmqIARyPldP3EE3TTDYFprSbbSSwoXwVQwCaYaBilMVvroABR4jkF@cbtuzpu6Yjg4lKJ3aSrN7kARy@Crandwggxv@UCjBmKBs3UzKUfaIaiSaspHheWjFEkZx4auQxLc3bs3ZWEfbMBjTtGHslTEK4UkBvQbk3YK8LZ6gTb4JKj2PkGYcO57IBhVG@CpIY0QFE4Q0Zm5DhCrwr68CAaAMCR@w2WLbLJtkF2YqVV2YyLzCQw5oxFMP7FIImAyh9dAOSpC4ivHAC1Qn/MIttgu/hkFGjngGQDgMvieiBsoXJqc3lHvJcMx7gwJYZKQtQUVj9@4tsKrVzF6SUYkQ/qk5xhlEqgd7Na4ALFBcP@pVxDRD46PVwDdsdkDxFKELrU7iVkerkaRMxNcrQYD/92602CKvVRUFVLEAfn3xXtEFkkFiJDuvwy7brjFVKyZZiHwXcO8SUmQdINTGm7OPZO2LIPAKMPxpLPh@FDCtk@isrN9urxsmYaCrTPHjPWiejjMD36AIN0CHzO9wEqQOU0FRTIti900X9ETarBHYvkxk1SQmW9gKJTyIj2s5hqcB8kl8UCqMzeCpow1HP58Nsj3VdaBCvbFjk9FHMkqFRzGgRQCP8u3lcbSn9jl@7M2vG0ocxcgjW3nY8hFjMmLpoHUfSou7JTquoZ8GtEkzYyCz7qjHtDJLUEMju352CC5JiQjhDqgbSOOOZYwApWPDoPN7XkVRBiCCTjtk3PCJCe1q@NCEEcj2lAecwMq5eWoqJ2h1WXL6eMyPm4qJodSK3Y9vzPANCVqOc8os89Tgk@2JJUM7HgOFC3SGNFB28QPCVnDHj5ZN47wPiE8UC35FeBS5s5SOpN1IzJM3n1l1I9HGGr2k8caEWrGMM92O0JeuS8GfafDmXmCqiwxOwbscslzDN9JTi6P5jdD6lOAbHauRvSsZF3HGCTEmBsa60CmMXeOM4ZyBgGMMMM1uYPYGezGU9qs0AFDfg56FNjwnbgWNNQEmbi/Rha7nM3ibfcSymoARuSU13@oZwMCqry1DhzBIiuXwJj2oGJlWLpCvQO8c9SAMzYT4zQ/TB60b3WRfddG82YYPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wd2J6p6BsQWAAMV2CykRBTADYlJkUOOkx/PTlv7QLxkgq7CSnNEIJPaoBCooKOLAeNNEa@yiZAwH3d45/u8C18np@fy2R2duqasuHhl8o8x9YtZTwwQfR2lIkxGvvfhDa7yjiAu3BJ/AOF8ng43pmhdFsr35vzpyD0vZq/byoR73txHBzP8ENcgxGZqEPbcB41qIcmfcSvm/C3cfH2p7XSF0H7q2D7k0rxKwTCGIKZpefpbhqApTvd03T/vFf1A86oQwJwqEUj8ERj0G7wMvIClznuhzGcCfLRMKhjndJSOEAS@QT5ImtewiDmPHj138fmDBLZxjnbc119nqDwJMbGBpyYk9jD5jDsUwg40az5BbdMbM4a89ZS8lmYHAa1cCOIi/bnhIvbgXIz1Rg@4@EzCJ/x8Nki0yDbxqzFRTL0usLiYKtHs6VBTAQzD@JccZPOixCCDPI4qFTkhzHnS35X8OvWKHVAb/4G9VgLGga0iTEQ3EgojRfNRrNle8b5ViulDKCxi0QIqHEA3WgRTc97oRupb51ZY8db8rLRWi2MSj7e6NUd@q2BtxUsY1hB1DA4vUw0MDoY@TtWuEDgFxggoBwGgSga7E0SZrIamkWnQGg4DXFBY45Yw0emRdKXH@T7gbjESc8JGwXUigBC/7BIgCaEsKDn8O9SBtzhc9eBOEFciT6lN0JDd/FWHCh5ratwXlOlSopgJUkBmkB2FFdr14sShENVNK4FRYp55dd/FP2ND0a/D/1iNfbUYPmAURWiXQU3iYII4XcXoiqr1yL1ChgoW7pluDByHXD51B@tIZstJVAzeD5YBO/cnHSHiUjld5O8fugoqmiLlbApzGs1KOK8xrsl7xcBSTnBw2Sen2weNAQ/PWcgACOzMpnhJ5tFk81qNc442GxNsvMIkjNCcsaT8NizNUi2/GSgPR0GwwtWTwukU9zFKgI8lQ@jIAaNRebpZwbuK3iFRjhxUcbPc8FzqBX4bQhFbGxn3dbK3BsRpCNM6xoAbIg3APT4J64rwnWGp0rhW8ijOCkDHsXf/GbAeQU0MGLBVW6oOhE2MtKBQeAXUzQOQN8VUw1BVGliHf8y/CemA8/gp970zCzHVJc9M@lrf/8gni2kbKSDRqQPNZNDhoyazHPbt/AalTlibG8KCg5IdZ1zhyVWCNvgr0z9pErHcjrKSMf9QfjhW@4rj@fJQH/ApSm2O3Ym@sTJ5SpcaTKp2a3Kn@sM5sB28HtZEWP1IOv1HMOz4xOo1K4zsE3PSDO0I3pq@GqH4X89Q4jKyb7T8QTB36nG1VgEzdsVirrttmmbk3Y7gRtAk5VwNzvtB8XmGY8LqP@CK5Ie2JMP9GiccDqvjO4keTdM/PKCn@zE7J4mjsZ@IE7V7jHgYV2Q/yF0CBIM85yF5khW3VGU7kwS9MWQoTNyBiD1TT1ZwNTXwB8uYCNC@nhMuKSZjiptJfL9DeoliW5aT/pJv/bBSdnXtISeDNNrywCWiJFm7nUaI2XdFdm112bHkwX5HX84vsdRfI9vx5e08Os4c9W8xgM/LOtsYgEBIi7QyN6NBhYd@FbvBjpLqITeKFfxBO@NYo/23/UQ0z2IuudHl/vQPtLhmwdvIeKfraP/7RUYJD943@rToduz4znwmxFuZU3QJw69YIU5AdEPk8h7bmYXNu0H75kXxMWvyz5EEQLEWGJcNhqkho45BrXbCyeQA8B3tHnc8naj3dM@uBoPXIGTe5Zmp9r6KnrQ7hmWPjd6CT9mOgI3KPEzUNiIX71fwZHREdNzuK6XgLHr/@3u@/fayJU9/8ZPodhkcId22yaBMCYmMWASn0MgF0hysoTxNHYbemJsj9v88CSZz733j32B3f/3EfZV7jvcv/Ypzta3SupW28YhM2f37GfnM8HdLalUKpVKJalU5cSpNI2D6JKpcgfL@O6149zNVpIljLmHd8oZw8bd9EP6lGjGFl9VdqtpHbC0lMN27HWI7c/BeDCWmAddiW@n5ajMP9KTcKfxbYIQHWT2LLtJtc488XmYj5t0jxkhzuulmwyX5AYivFRN9@H3kejbLaXOtQpVTS9n0tF@Zvd4OK/HLa4wPCmHUfdjyW8x3b15zmI1AZaIsO3vm0KmIMMsptXK2xDly9we6/emZAK@8T5d745ZpTlDoMYlWdKNQl5us37hZLAybtAvNpze0S8AngejpjCUaRv2tHTIWMUpl/7A0lr0F1LSCYpFRSG5RsPKlTHPlP3z17jO1p11tqbqbKXqjEdAukorU6aVqlL3ArpnXhd0g87oDumMJKyd6Wee2Kb/en1/iN2Kz0vhUiV01dL1UoUE8lKwVKnnSSgvtZcqO/wQLVWO@OHTUuWv9JCMraUvSxUzLJBhSK/88ALftQjHe2upsp13vmZG/qcgMvV6S5W4TynPc3llihAp0G7SGnHE1uvrZo6GAU1srFS6ChwTuVg@8T6My/9K9L/E7@LIPkjEHucjzqyWVTk1aVgzhtRD04aJHDFjJFf0bF4/2GWzsjgLqlmmNZ5dhsGTGp5bSgsjQQypfKJBv4Qg5GZlNkbKmsnuiY6unTiUOzldP1PPY32gnef0E8p8mlTCQdt0edNfaRDSgffDE4XvwnMKHVMdY4QzWWcGWiDqz0tzGoW@TuOie9/uId7rTmcibAsmi/QSg7VkOulwfDiHygb9QZpJOBW3GEK7DG/KyaAE904UY6mgR@YdyfxZtwyCwR78zrzmWOWAWkoEIfGkdCqjLJ4XWBYjKZF1lqYqg49QsGQOjfCg9YkD4u3oR84n4sblueKuaciUlSpZcqXFJBX24B7syh9J7fHitQ6nYd@3fDUlb7HXkgcAq2Rci8jX/nfo733R341CbYgwUcEsxXr2VDqtXs@dZScw7ybVTncgEl2148xUjuIaEpLT6sDSzOfx2pSKD5MPUfKl0hj6hLZvyBavCb5Bt8m1hcCCljC8Tn/8tEIfP63cTahpjaR77RmlxUNNGo40PMY0adp8XKXhs7oYKby/7Xe/u4OH6Q62Ow/wuAHDCZLLKB9e9djKJRnbJLblC0RquaJEkPNxadzNyUcS93x0Gx/b0oeD5uHOwf7eB5p0nz596ug5epzgh1GLvdZ4HhfIbKMezwczli0rLqJW4bAb2/HRRX84evCxl52SJSKsSRnwqRbDfnqMO1qWWfJ8YuxSOclrUVTD@pQMAz8llaDq@JiyQ03XEREkGOUf@RqIUW@J3i6v1hyOz9Rs9vzLoNnk6cuEu9azGLrGnIg7f889KF5FQw7rLMHFbjIZ9tOhdg7U@1e1Y3X8qq52327/VX04eKve1/aP4aLhzdutvca2on/1/aO6yqRMJxGIEQtKoutO0AoQXVetlEpPFEPe7g/GInfy2458P/Iv1at@K8Ax1bPIv3xxIS9eLxhtSqk6LUfH2MMMOfDmZTiCvQVHiqRlLJSbNt@8xKUKRXnPaE17iTXvZb8ddkLKm8HadxAGkbmsp7oh9SDJW3Nf3RUlCUEh2XSIg73CAuuGivuUH2c3BMYX@yuQGDkkimTbU5pw8X/fTcHj@uHrIwVvH9sH@zuN48bB/pHaPTik1zcfGvsviZ6No@PDxtZbJHHG1wc7jd3Gdo0/CAIlT8ENxy9X0WguCh6yM1Van3Dy7Q2o@@O39K43NHh14/Md1EgtXfUgfUK/G/4WtJc2MlcR1Bfce@WjApVfrB2@fEdzvgp@xQmnOQpm@4Ps24gDlS6W1DOujQbLJo23DT1cadorlB0@j7gcK8QqCjbYPUeen11lgLMRTzsMVHYbNirY@xYvHjyWDWiq6AHBBihjsFJVHGNsacl9xiA3qbZWtw@Xq1KbGBHqFxR9YUxNNjJMMW0rA6C4NtLoYT@ovBF/IL6nDyu62tFQMqjH8QfJoJ7IB6iiDdiOqFWd42p0cAXxrNbkwy@Xg10@FlZP4w9bPq9i1zVO0m/cpb6KYzTCp0mXI8nJLg9Hu/WjVhhykYjzI8patysDI5D4niQT5SiRbdsoZ5aETQdHDdrsTcJmI5W4AXZCfmcUqXzV8dQxjIOCXigx/M67fk9MoBLTHeY9tQ73UVV9xT2MY9/xRZxBnxkQcTfTeMTldrRWGNy3HJXcmqrR1zaSHH/WmKB9C4GtKQT@CBgCVEitdFo8U/G1YIDpdzQr56M@cST2bX@38xM7t69aQaqAttrK/xL@9pujieym1knGTpGxoy76LRiSWslHmZ3@kMY4i1WOFgYp2LroD0ah9GE@3QI@ceJpjnJjYqPafq5upmoDHSZr7PV7VqVnxMV31HpGTHmfWpnj5ew8Fl9JGGnifJqExe4O6Phn/evAOjtzcYh0E2D7hRRhPivH5ud4xJiI/plJZMfvCtFn16ubO1sfC7//7CIErYgFiQBtjA7xjxgTddHw4HM@NlgcQu/SI82EDoyuzlBa2@BpaYlRboDROvAipHXdi@ZGnCbmxtPfcUlp8jt//PKlKqUKkEw6bHh0kU@km6tOTJUulzlV2gTEkp2ELMn6vPniMsxYXr/AxST0Avwh9SBHsG6fCMynRYhp3dlVhySLjo@suzuG76hNtqhIgsvjwpHdH8Wf8lvV5U2nmBiUKIuceSOiXQO57DiWWQrPV1PgduaDI/l9f3Drc7GT6eG7oO3MhfZduBWW74Yl05IF6/5gf58DVia3PwSW2u7eDVgmyWloMafHzOku5mJr2vk1/jzVdzz2CAzmXuygxECt2q56fERtHJjnpYBjg0kUoqPjnfrhocrK@oTKktzDkqGtxSBgP1BvEmvbsMfCzouVpnixHCtP5kvKoi251XX3YJ5JvDtEhdZBXE2PWFgkbtI74a1IPT2zsArB1vcsEA3l0th9NjIoOtGAv9IakJBNOs1qYGZmM3My@YSRbQSu6eaKbmzb8LOFtczdiDo8HNuAbJsg/xw3S2b333vRjyumHlGw4EQKDW6TJk3zDa0TjqjiAWX0vHQPzukW06UwshcFO2doB8OvUlrD/vMMxYwkSrjowpZY18qxRk3040Wj5rBBIqYBH5aeOlEsminBiHj@8szuUCeZ9PLpKYiUTMShfWFzBRU//aqnMKZGPE9WY4XcHmuLjM2JwfIUu7Ma9sbdmR7CFnptUjxMVkXSdm5VhX9MVTJLpGoyNJ/ZGJNIkNdWVx9/C/ZkK0zxwp@FLXPIpPwcXQ5ofZ@AjMYRb@8T5zb2XZOeMMAc0olpvRkwEwVJ1Zkxp6TazpORjR/hIvtChAy8/iO072StjrqdwG02dJmRbOicZaoN1hCOGyqjZor6X@dXB4H8zfoefH99MtiQCaaDX2GV/7o/jILkVp7lKcf6BA8D6W/BcNjjbHKf6RJQ8nyNae5lO75tJwav0iok8nmb3ZKOvp0kZreu2WvgSnh70UM0b@zubUxu7xXKG3ZTdxt7dfWIvYB2UnuR2WHWsWTPg7A3DwGWwbwvgemD7/A9jCr0j3BwDUgiE9/myzNtnG/ixhQhrfmEw0Jps1AtW8uTvd@JWn4PvlXc7MNIZd0fqCDvwtYPdp1ZO@uljVR5Qi4a9PJUys0WvCwXpW/Y0AWkNAjpTXy3Jizc1DCWkrhec96HfRQOtoJb2T1jy0m/WF4vrf2Y4db13JF7efLjqfuoVc0qmnz93mV0NbxpfzrvX1x3VFcNfjm7bY1/@1Wp1SfqMdW18oO4Yi6vVYvs/fYp/V1XP5aYczWCz9mtNKJLexJ2V6kllazDNx4ohx940VzBDYkJLlWPLg0X4ordqHp5snZa7VVLG5cnvdMNXPIbLVdHy@XlPD78QLMoyRg5mT8ZnWJOtXddg961gsNTDu@qr4YovhpCX177w7C/V9t/mdqNgwKALTBt680b6hLJewHWbLh74vWCm7zeJnMVODYDBSmzwLeCyvAJwPvJ2I5ph4QZ9YpL2mx0y3/HTmah5F0NRn1OMe4twVrqS/gls2CuMZV4R4GynITGCSbuFxCcJE8eB0PydSxW1IWyqGtl3J10LBAnKMniMPsxm8WdQiCq73KdnGYiL/BbF0ACoeu/cDH17BkHsidWizzexYMphz/kCxOlUzziAIR@BnzagCpYc4/42keGmo/3Mh7kC@9RjfieDBvIZ1hTRArMv9Vnvt/E5Z8RAYTwC6JzeXqLU2tepEjK3UHeXIDvuPTCH8cMuFYpnbKAxgK21FdNgLOlONMI1Woy0feFG5BTaEX/6RYUyvw21Yw4vyPZmSR8Tq3fItCSu5STNvHTTYrlrWIFU8xktkix8E1qYKeLlkevAxpWY7UddLuEtNBiISEHHvl@r65/Oa4/OkGdpzHykl6YSi@k0j1JF6SSXB5N8Emmip0pm/uc5Puqskk2d6quqmLlxaOebnmkkiR5N@bljbxRvxkmmTfjrhSujBOepRIKVspPM3pfUh6kysQMHqefSLrm7xXd8zGWqbwv0vXjN6M7KGDjWW1rMsGlXi/sPs/oqOc6BWyWJWoqJcU5mqUyg6qq72BqcUIaHPb5edhuVhMoy2UjcXjMZDefvch6Wsl4np9EQ24xTg2sGWPEohLXucyEu@ULi1QPJz@wQDBMMJoyI3fTFB7rwmMLLHI9MNXKLcipAU5NmxziVdyL/II/ZrCnkTP5crMTFwTzW2m83G5OE4iF7oPsbDKlpQmui8hH3ag5s0hS93gS4mwhsW/tAsd1BnIHu4Nt8AexnLAFhZEUU3SPUzSlkwxlw753dSESv2b@XnyUeemTjj3oBreqhmWGz7ewMqkL7qMgGkXwrsWOf6KrwaCLU0dW@G74CrWOLrCyiuOWBKI1s3uZBix7JL@LJ30hnQp56gCQb2AgkiREV@fnuEyGG7D9G4hW7LiEIy9T641lQ4PGzOMVuWYeKDjfYAHcDc9tJKTnZPSA0tHAbwVehnS0iLSfjDS1E@oYsLyfjnsjcOJGU1olk/mXq7D1afslznOflkuPyxbJrvVxcMl7/CS5YEVEMgkr8MO4Wn6SyVhnwy05Gy4AoKv2MNG/I94MroNeL8jUaMbgjBEprVEwvA7aXiZzGMSHwIALVsbJJO5h96@GLdncIaXLJ2bELeHIleMw4jD8Yn6W4@IWn5W5GRxaJafN1NXXYRsENDdOOn2cDvOBBdwECD1Q6DIYEVEeOSqNEp89a1xYd7nERhRRA35OrLOJmAy9/ihsUc/wTlamS6DkGCSprNeewITqa3V9XA72ZiGA6zEJBQwC5ihpHg4ZfWj@XTgo3TBzxu6bnimS9OvzWKHhHgxDkr4JgblXuJiFO3Xw8avGkTo62D1@XzusK3p@c3jwrrFT31FbH/iMGwfl7NhYvTrYI@kSn6bLqfkBfcjWjqhklhMytf0Pqv63N4f1oyN1cKgar9/sNQgagT@s7R836keuauxv773d4dN3gqD2D47VXuN145iyHR@4XKsplknKqYNd9bp@uP2KXmtbjb3G8QeucbdxvI/KcKpfU29qh8eN7bd7tUP15u3hm4OjukLDMjuNo@29WuN1fcej@qlOVX9X3z9WR69qe3sTDT14v18/VGwkYLVyq05Y1rZoCYuauJ07jcP69jEalDxtE/EIwT1XHb2pbzfwUP9bnZpTO/zgaqBH9X95S5koUe3UXtdeUuMy@W9Qhfpl@@1hHR6UQImjt1tHx43jt8d19fLgYIdpfVQ/fNfYrh9tqMzewRET7O1R3VWIUMlVEwyiFqXT89bbowbTrbF/THPG2zewd3Cok98TYQjLGhXdYQLDDAKtJSIdHH4AVNCBO8BV71/V6fshaMrUqoEKsKjYPrazUYVExGO7mWq//nKv8bK@v11H8gHAvG8c1R3qsMYRMjRgkPGBWIcqfcutRj8RXvJIzJoxnOtyd6rGrqrtvGsAc52bOOCoobmFybb9StPcg8djaxMl7GPPwL@0N1Y605@uA/j4nN6Rmb1HE3tM2j7YqdOMrJ1dZZOEtzTrrE@4UrLTaKaJE@k15bKmHZxdnTfDXqePO6ZxMdn4uIzOXcRdchC05mNmTvgxvb/CBXK5ZvNdrUkL3aNm03HvUzKFxrdK6G3webkc3UYEtcDKGxs/lYrQ/VmKUJs/6INONtTDAQRyCvV/ENM3/zJwVLHYDnQxXN4HYLN1FMmxyQWOUkg08mVHRNtJquSdCX4PNTtwwbwB77Wa2CeFZSRn6kf0p/cleZHJwfpA0lm2u4pFLGIZjfC3wFQjlbBLBP6jPRKEHa7Si4Lg03m@ZFeHNb933u@3845jynDeEa0Dz/PON4qfBecTxQuT5RlZPnbW8SAis@5mFSY@f9YkU7pfvCG3LI8/zRH/OAYb8fmAXVOuijer9aZl/gcpDoskV2nXFrhewZ0Mne917W@N91jNlVaebEx8fxV/l7EFe0F4A6YJ74TLnfLPq1PJQAOMfXEQSULtIaNYtMoYe5M48w1lvECmm7ANyx@aqy8CnteJJKTIXvldu07MxsPw1sae5PDLw9rrrbe7uyQ6ge2T9dWnaxuZ2O3W31z5/YB62GEvex0b0DxOehonWaNkmxQfHimWv/SE/ZmBi0VkhEN802n8EX4eYruNtCUTBBmaGyH0VA8metkAdMgqdsDxIGP4debI1AyQTzXVQWsu/VtW8X3SlZgHtDFLd8y9dos/gB0PfzPE4wZpBtIsxi6MiXNpdcFyL7trTEV5ccOOe5DFyxo@FjduMQ14q4vtZ3G7lt80b1u9GIkpI8YrdzuXJCQeTGKhjF1FT0b2G/YzojeA2XsYffmb5jd6/KAd3LG7Oz8a1UZHRMbduCT2qZPNaN3oEw35FAFK4FTN1PRMYZff0Ujx2NPbybFjEGs0MCqItgMb3zTgjdiPyGSVbAH7YslRn4VT4bwDcDY0x@p34txZzdFQNoz/EP1uvFIogRU7ORGq3cR1ZEyWD7EfC0POFJn@FD0Y/j@RJjPgP6MVJ0FPqGU5AbwXJRmq0IqWr0yU8MYcNFinGwk17U8fEjBf7Y65iBumT29u5X4NkUD3zth8@MBuDzv5GQQAk2Njwx6/sUnahU9LpxdZRxfHOUmvdTnIKz1XmKliCm5h7dRltcs1Zyt4cZQje01WhXtUVL2QhdsZj3paMk0s5dXDKCvgHOP/o/iIN0DiAc9ceiFWq5OcVdKjzMgB7WrJmnDascckUku/3nlq90hZLjJTsl@ffBlCEehN4DPdTo7U0ldinpv2uMgzsTpmL3hwy45lMiYf7bLujA0xuwHgPGzzZgiCuYxuMEF0BTq76kugqfxDNhRBJYnVYeJnEOLW8Yi0PK3exNjzziQ4NMb@bU8iAgSyq2VyeOLgQ2NoX5f31Gt/TCh379dsYbHio6O@C9tFVCbbEro8Ate0@v0hqY4@2k04uuHY8dR7vekQ9KKrofZfSPNZONQ7Ekbpp2qgNsnqnacZccXPqEXhCLcV2h7zBzfpMoCFqLgnuS2sqTwxr@HRTbPpGN4ul1X@WZLyjGjCbkmZiM/UmvryRXIJQbXL0IApGEbx4oJtNrkenDvEw@@mP/yEuR8qUK8dtGPPpBZI3guUTmr02MdjayRNH/Qj3tGgrsAOSEyJsmykxYaqNEc/1eyk7ZqyiXdM@C7llnx/PTGTGmspqihhXF07Md9agToTVFrRrkFjZ6HllVVGZdaC6@udizH2Fpo@tlbZj71YpFREiag@NKojnkRuxk8f8KQ3@asPI4we@oIzbq2CAmHorDhXnZZzjB9sCt6HwbBt74mSJtP2B9h@46VPv8e8aLYOtdu/lj@KgjGtAFrF8LbIMJr5v/Qves3tftc/D/uhT@s0@NG/FYmHxzE/osPOh/2biGMycULbytQeJ8/iX0bcsOE9PpfcsFxzRaNgkLfNFEbDce1C3ETwzjmMAJN4sMzfg0kfaXGZJ6tJoUz6/inb45WdjTvLPi7PKiwn@gCgBdzmhAWF3CEd8cUk6/LpxlSGs3kZLBzPVEH5zh0WeymMfyQS8TFMCmODzJRZgt0IrMzuxPikfeu22QfhEI6Wgp0AgYWiPH92fYTYJinyHJYCFVVeL1lF5RTlFn4I8TC@m9wrT//J2BMCfwL98uNZ3DKLEVjEdYy3pUjWK9rLKOHC5oEhy2iWxCTFwvOwZ10/5Cget5NQ08nju6jBlj@kFGk3e1NciRGZp4UPQgfmmyRymmMHk8qSWnLYbwdUkNooX7qbYYNv2c/y4MchruycQTBta8h5C@m7SNUiKiGI8YR5rY2y@FT@9ohZWblvr00QsDrL5MwKpp3PGs2Fb6CEMr/iWKs/JGGcnaCeNvVYikb9wdI9qXen7JjpmW0WrVuO801DYGG2Kk2Wj9pM2uoYj@ONzCQ@E0yTphhbmhEPYfnKzzGbTxLxttrEeKs2x9@gw100S@ym4kkl7u@2jH1Mitew6DUTTTykGHc4Kd2Iv580qeHNuyWIhinLqyZLjCZERnMsjxaoCTLFVLo/hZj7NO4T9GgT5VBvm2hn98@dRJ00kjMuT01Syskl6AnH7bi0SXJp0IHxBdzEiYYbC6lY4bx1x3yUVy6cwckwEgQgtOKgkOxDyQ5u0lkTfMTRATr5JqyFypBE9LRpWzjETv9jgrFXfr25oy0emuNC@XRDIN3GkGhVwbnmQTL3zen1pHnLUKZIQUN8BiniFk3Jpov7t@rPtoXyEQQpzcna0rfkojGOWiZs6I@d1LyFDpxUpUumRlR6IDRZNNBYoFXKeTeQ5Sq0v3AoHA/rBj2MaAEhn/P4WdYl4M57rRRTG0Vu22NkcTS5ZbQ5qrApRRKGkneQXw9FUXV54UoAAsGYylfLBAFuTRl7HAqw6x2b81KI6j6igtUyhiV9ZK@oiZ3njHQQVWd4smrlKM3K8aMNozATCCkWs/MkiJDOMjtLAoUmupm4WDmezm5PkoMUYsP7QnHqCt0raRrGPScE5OjdJSeRKCdl5ZY0B3Pik1UnlRjzN6f@WLJSS5OpRJ8Yw5NCeTJ1vZRKTVW7spIumipJ9HDsWlOJRArHRjiWCn/uP76aYrs8j21CrUVGSsvQ9tmIrk6rTFq3eb9E6hlfyjY6hoFn3ww3y6@mhFhJOWWf74BdLfGRAXy3/@nWGstUg4mOFcB@6cxll7wsCFljzWKqR7Ow0jWe9mIHBWZN2@@od8e7uym3r2djY2h0GQxXS6USmPjMdn5vbKuxlRT2i@ncxc5Vt1sc3Pxl@O6syLI/CDgkQMWsoAPqEhoUkdcfnktkCOBAWZG7oC@yYq1/1enYIRhwQonOo26TnNobguIJKIyNXt4d8wYQg9QT7M9oINr3s4pH340viqaGYo6hqDRMgq@z5vSMyIMPHdhnxydVDAyC2Vgz0bzlVDc/YwZBZBPuLHZf7HxOzJOzr4Jut@@q94jqDE8BC18nC@zu2gVKkgUnjHy79ypif7SuCq7DrnWvGFlsXgc4MzGZOBPGLzx84x8G5/XbQT578lOWphVq8jKauQz/1K7Knmcd7Sz@HmCFDwnte@W@9Af5FtNpMjNN9XoEJ0@E0eOyO3Ptk8ri8J6Yptm3c4Oos9H12FkDNd1hXcD4sufu5ZbckT0mbvbjbbkDGpYEhsYJPlfuVwJXzf55YvF61OncTypyGADp2O@SiBIJ5c8JRD4D4BGohx/RE160/1qgYb074VBEFBwE65iWOyjQRIFM5mGr@utNvlarqcXB8rKq1bbooVBQta2a2sGHrS21Q@9beP@hurK6uiEyd8f5TB@3zMevaotg8A7ncutiuEOvlFbFvTFYa6OLF4vVRXdjsVl9trkRFU9qW7jWT0//@W//9T///b8Va/rlf@Bli19OfoozeZ5XXGx9Xvzh6wbeT3ZOlxbPThYHp0vnG@Cyv7PX8H5jVPAT81FveJbJySxgfWU7UrPOZu8zuqgywQMv/eEnki4VlWtFxZz@GknkKJaxuVZgfQ9wj/KMlvAm6MDkUp6QyBHQMbbjqXdaAQzwaL4hShIusAOV8nK2Yjbu4Q4mzhCfquS0Jx7WWa8D3GlJPCngLi7NWIWwFwU97IBfs84rzctkfPoNR03Nv8WfXkfnW/1b9ehjXj0qqUeuepTN8k957Uf66iwWQ9zOlWy0HMhmXUpJjhZgZqiikBU9Xj9wrJ0JcmcyixyyB5CMmwrOLLfg3Hj1x5dlJOBadJ5ZQCxTJVskfMiEIrnPi72v1C2fKcfXbOqqDSsKTb2K4cqsE5W4f6EC@ZEYAiQ1XwpBKn2qEid9fCMZT0XzRfd1hqMJMWCQ9fDlLo97fKC5aLGnbZ5TaymEOWLzefmKuXFDLkMz2kiR@hME@EBFlpMlvkm4lFvKiJW31UpuptzCttunmU9sHcbByNimS6HflcUEYs1tE26xp@@1aENuOV5R2TA@XrGqyk7afquMVeTyqjsKB/q6AteOAfU5ru2rjCT0KAMSOOKzvzI9wnijwHiKmugWCZY1Vu0@mi4joaevplMHO56cHFlEKP6Up7H9ZWJsO0W@JWLYQXiAkYpN@Tp@2I2015UhE/vcH54hOqDf4YBqIzk34/08xKSdwLjfiZH2GDKbnCfjmZqSGwz980vfVbn9/vHQHzdo2iLNZ9TyHGohXDABCQw@XfWs5hmEpUW6S5gicVPYcgjBC7pjHR5N@jYb3zlBl5qhoN2uYBCk2IkpGXxJ9dUEHROu/o5OsFGeEt7xaaQWsSx5YWmkIWXtazM8zKaGTsbUYI@deOBkM4JqPDINL@hCV5hoL/nglyR5Fz4CdN1ZfQtQX0VY4@DAmJ3Og56fmpwG3Yy56F/cUDIvYjxzKEqxRspoKE/LScQ7YEV65E9pLxAyNxl3RpmFfH7hY6TDueXseYSdfMe2@EVfhXEAOg5gxjdD1NteKMJyYoZKYmB4qsGW/wSh0/XPCb/xjT8GK37M5Z8/KDonP33snT7Kf@x9@fibw5hokWxm2YLK6cNsI7H0WKGZseimXo1VWmRcDX7spTN87Cm5w2KRgBAp5k9@Kp5@KRJCH3OO86j4MScESXUZMCnOr68I8MUpNHNpLIq5zILzyDGdn39edhTNrfyLPpQPjvwSFmZRydv0tM4ZdggU39P99UqunETF9ZXSk5XyE1oJnQe3hWFwhfm2EF2dBbekSkRYztLU8/G3FDekCPH1NvI36OMttVPCmsjdk0hfUtIiVA9zricTsxWV8YQnKD9Rmd2l4oqLE@fxcfiIBb@riOVMXvYFJaaDFvflMX9G/UvU40eQa5O3Q4QjYWUgNiK8hVoAZBN85S4OdcxwWeJ7Tp7ahu9WBkLdW8xZs0Wv3ytoZc3xljagROPWTHe9tF6aHKNTQzQ1Qhe1MrX0QJU3nz/9j/9@8GtulNtcKb4f0u8o92tubT0nj/RAb4/N23VuM/cM2da@5sZFWgPT49P/@J9UfvMvBAcp42f0Z3PVwFob5zYLVS7yJbe5Rg/llRWq93/9679SGxZlxYZYrItNVzFiG4Yi236PeZfSVQOtlGXpUiJW@GIWYIiFIa3N6QWGUbcr6yXepstpq4rrQHu@MvYoeopnw6wRmwrJToaxpyDNSApUUUFBQBoTio6ybDeM2QaYN0FT/fzQW4toBfCzNueIq4xNNx5GMBlalGURdWBeaqT1vDxslp5nY/OOStbYlGwYFRJLOy1r1x9vEDu86QejsJW2kjDD9bLl3wRnHvjQC9pXtKbqRd3@L8PiNbHkZXllvdjB5n6R7biLA4ZUGIy930gR1MGAaGHIRqeuGlIP9C/hwsvlaEGk0O/GZ1ImniRp2YOgJXtY6ZjElEXu@LlyPIzmeIkqnee/pMAjcqYOBGnFSvvYo5IHhxWVXY4zSj5e8zrA5g0bx2oXGAWxhh2wbPIy3AbsDpr2eLXhOV9C4lLwui5ZPL/dbvo6LZ9ZyJpQaW5m4SLoDqrZjrh3h@9UnJho@ouaeSeUQogdhEKBBR1gXQYjn5bo1Sx/wXo8qQFuUvRZa@wqLiFrR@fVq/p2laOuzKn6Rqq@oR6FlpDUE/OM5Y1N2dlEtlSxVTkMmjhSm1kx1RaZoM1Dj3@AQSTd0ujgWoJuDt@AJKolzdFWZXa3ubwWJh65CeTOnmwtSuTqTC65/OiaHHKDGroT6vWkMhIQ8IJbgYUyvR/JDYiqCTMa9jLiz28i2fj30GC4DQdwJWq7rRPnozIt9a4R@yYc8V1KRSTQfmVtG@yMzB4x6NjFVhyCNouNl6wDlupUeLHFGU13VDgMtHEJlc3KPtVJS8XhZTs6eq0EiqAP2VJ55fGT1bWn6z8iytmCbu1sMCjkYRUwuPAJBmvUeVpk43u1ml3KyieEoJ6uEtBngcUBHMy6bhzHuH2@cR5UyyUNrJRlWDccRkOK6@1KBplAHAYeZgRao@SH2Xz@eeUEDTv92Ha@0D/ib@MfkBnOuKP1hfRWP7xJPFNlLsXhQJUFMzvFyT@GBxVHp9h5g37nEN4mAti6CttTRXvwADG6GPavzi9s7vC0a6tjGjBEcPZLjRXUy2CUOBizsIIuqjccGtbti6qBdzLdAhjlYkqAzifAaZhpv5W@tjTF6FiiSQieNXFjFUeIlumozc7Mnb2@qu/vTCKWs8PQMVzPtmwl5Y49mcGBDGL1Ws09Jupqbxd8lVTLJDflVZkFXAn5ynwd3sdd6RYCUVtUMbKa9YZRfh5ZysyLiWvTpCj1I/CaAbNc@jYpzb1W0woQxAhCvZsUCzE3Ps@xSZbgZHcyxil4OVuxbERfh1HEDuZ0ZVlHW5RyJo4qsJC5AyD2bUpZaUipgh7lxzoHXpbeRjBHuRWNrQFthhyvVIOZOTnMBFvdRuIAG1HHDS3Q/sb@tqt26vRn9/2OC0V5q/ZXtDsO8Xw3vmWNb7miGrumC2xvsWxzC5upX3FFiZilpB3GJghC@HYkKmKQeA2oN3Y17WVQn6TG9mnCFWBXXyvhZndUDxI4euE9kAW9eI9dcfB1Hf5Wkc2raUkTu1TRw0K2uOYPbIsmC0mtMSQh5T1ArEyCiB21JNy@kDC8WKCz5u3rtYth7MbubJ5OsawsqEht3y0S2dM8eydl5rHFimaLlQr6cR5fMN/O5Y2zoNPXd9Fi5vgGbzz4Y7xRuD9zFP6/YI76P4c7HmvueFyB7BHuiN2G841ODsPen8ExZ2Oeg5vt8DzE/lDHekUjSq4FgAUeMMQdUkosl9C2O8SJys9OWJ6cj2AktLKKiwF/qPFPdOOfVCBz@XEn@H@18YV/cONXdeNXK5hrZvS8Vu0sd@v/mBYnKmE@/WFm90LdlWzOH23pmm7pWgWz6Yxu/r/e0sL/oZY@1S19WoHHBDlwEPf187lZNJHa0XajkZhbeBnttCuPOPazudLB2qtdzdLiodO9ii6q0NbVH8Z/XeO/DmnETwhDh7OI2DY0XsvL8lQuy4tmybscCpespCXSXuMZ3WqvnrCS9YieoERI88bWUC9USCF3JTE5bfIS/TGRvvHkc1@cRbbrYJk4OLcW0LIiLDvJEBfNVwfJXFmL55Ud9oGsto8P95b/i5Dh0v@kb6ER8ujam6DbNTOJvQQ7jr1O6cZYzQHsI73mSLGKJicjO9K3vWN2WbhbqrFji4l5cfYiQY7acP5Ha6lL6BtWVG5sGRFtPF3erKpgmmuWF/KF2i6ZZjdZt/gPcemPmkt/rKhDvTC4i1S@3vDTvJis01ZWV@fNAVLKww8GYMml/HNG1f8G)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/98dmi)

Funge++ supports `HRTI` fingerprint, bff supports none:

```
@,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@

         ^ (^#4H'R'T'I'          < IP
```

REBOL3 doesn't like `^(` for some reason, hence the space. `"HRTI"`  `H'R'T'I'` for Pyth.

Answer (score 1):

## 378. Befunge-98 ([Multilang](https://github.com/TieSoul/Multilang)), 16400 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::&&1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?MLot ~7+5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##       @,,,"371'_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdtVVdUl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYk8daz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBldn/OdnXTy2tZQcBYe@5gOjLsiVcRYkxlzNLtwVQfGKxvWhPDTTPPMFjHsJxzCNcY257aU8/o1eEty5htnLNDu2v2AAKbOKeGbb4xXAjLMfbAsC5HlxPWdUYj3e55bOya9oRC84w91eGlP@2eMr3jTVy9OzEdG4IKjD23LX3U6emMoo9dgycqMgDVPaU0yyElxp44rmdADk7X8DwHPcvgqbum83jv04@vxVcz7GMdkBpbxuxa9qrKPjcNt3c9hcY@O3n48Lpvln1Ncmz28CZKao7tTSfO4eQ6/DzbGxi2zjS5LGvXAwtAzIlhlTKlzPWgItSnMTG7S/lAwEPThdrV/VpkXd2G2sK63GLGaDyZM4nXv25ZYd16TPfY1JvqFsWzp6OO4QYRvYnuTkx7wM7NyZBNhqYXpqPY3ljvGlLPsMyROTF6zDIhkdP3oQBou8dOjfm540KV@zAd25pDQqNr9k1MEuABAPFKTIYGhzPS51DJ9gQaB9OZB2hYRgAtKcQg/gOjMx0wZzoZTycMcOuZnt6xAGhnznpGX59akzTrQBgQmfzPh4btN2YAJwOIE4dj9WpKqBmLNq/3eiwD7RjwODWYCVQjtCosmwV/5rhANYgVYOQDo3bNy2jMoM6givpOheUzGQg/CH0QW93yHB@ZZdQw0Ia@SnWGcJ@6zsDVR0CNnkE0/ezwKfO6jgtv8MO4vD/dBqarT9j2NosffPogzuphtchuRwirqMYuoApiQSA7060ptJBoTThQP26YWsAqi2/EKywOZNEyLJdjOei2JablgUhqpgwO6P9aVoVfgWklllOhB@Xjacyn7@oD0zI4lAFCKWLD1/JMg3smx7JqicccOFafR@tSZkWWLbFCkRXzrAj3MitrkBuCzjG1nIdfAX4ArQyoqPDL5jigRbuHdoptbZ/19ZFpzX3oBL7L8iorAkTAVwXIWgkgwDObxV8WfoTW8hWFPRkCtYf6GYCXLPMUuZERMiSsQgUeytaWQhwRWS7P3hti9kA6IFq@xIqQfQEokQMUgLJaCbLPZ3hBvKFhWX6yoYfJCNtiBn6AeRHoUALqZ4CWGSRmEX7wDvxOA8amARfTgDFpwEw0DdxZzALiFSCsAFVZ8Ok11L1TyIjno/WI@MDRAYyK1EYmpiKRAALUFstCnRVYDhpCFhtCPssAf8ClWGDAx0oqK@VYqciAnuUMg7pRAS9sJSrwTxXwUREY1L8KDUAFnFSgtgpA1WyeCRFiq1kMh7RZSAukUXOQJgduqDi1gD9IBy1DhSxVyFPTyotGCLhpeShvPkutUytA7RYhDOimAa4aNCcNsNVKEI5pS0DDEjbeYjzNCaEjHaBWsLlDOwRi5AEfggtxwa0Vs5x@ujUe6h3k1jxlp49JC9gNCkhGSJrB4sEzh9QEVDIABnsBoK9BC8gCObJQtdlcmL2lApAGgjd6JjFoywTepYYUKqapQb7Sx5MF2dQCYTSeT4ahn8b9HGCcJjA/Y6B352Eg9L50GLjwLWTRVyNeuwCUyaGvB5zVmXrWAkjoyGmUlXFmWgu/Evn1DL3XN73h2wWuOcqkY@gT2zxd5JLPpyNE1SMBBQxY8ipmo3EnpgTD1WCIrkVZtCLGGTthBS2hrKqEXsfoT@2BIZVLEfwoZDJ1JzCwLPIsc2/XHAxgTF7AUdNUTBooF955wtDKZidC6InUxTxdE4bve6w7BIEiDCxz@OXyAkZWQxhzvYOjugRSGIwCZRy3@uaMde51adRYIJglOnWH5jiIXFkbOVK5lMmsVIi0DaLcm1ImZM14teRXjmkn4iyeFK4EGGu4ZBkdqWFA@xxHKRx3senCuOqQ1LBgnwk7GBmTQLTlQR5GXQvYKFRKV8cRGMcjg8bTAI45kRlkAmKg4Zyh2EqD4lI2Hg2cHRelVJByeobrMowLoq2XpiHWm3Y84/UU5agFXn0Ysw0Y2vu6aYUI0DiiT0gAgGfcg/zmy2j3XWdEg80Ih1DLccZrxBUYsM8R0CPn3FigvhjP9fHYAqkJ/A0utAEy5zrJ2yScR3PlCEEiTAcVDgApK5A2TNfoEu39okPqLMglyyhWmFa/l0Uo9yPiVBY6C4gaHqaxp5ZVATnH6LJsXekZZwr6cJFrWdRCHAIhDEQpH0RHB1kZMScsQkj3NJnEu5OgZj1ntFw0Pr4ehkUfmigYWef6HGqvD0OrMdNHINEzFJuh57IRtBheg1gToLNgsQ5Zz7HjkxDKuQtCLBQ6LAkJykiTiTkyQPtxIAnWeI6QxtGdMOvMoSkTtXIyqTsck2uEkoXrhOIeuYgH7ywg7vWmXaQa5m3a1IJATPJQxneBVXI/YeKyZlOHnwvy3NjX8GR0YMRjRC2iIHi8t/uSd5cgooxq2B6oFZ7MTNS/oOUPnD40tnMTyg4MC5IuYHeJCEiC0Gsmd2WBSI4NaHRqMZN1x2MG/jAoQfN8mCmBCOq8MtkbCLSGoEJ0p647Z7Mx1IQ5gliTrtPvQ@t9Y4yHAIKNeqw770L3hErG1iP0HGIw3fFyMRdvmwbEsVEp2X/682xgANlBYO2jdopNflGA8ZiKQKTQbS7M2jpQCovQHc@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@@uZy9ii96cdc3ZdC@@ip/zKE850l/VRAXdB6IBOlIj3vXiySv6UMhIkKs54olBSfhchIkWSocoTfdDpYZB4CIzmeG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ5MyGU09gmoCtexQ/UBG83oFPo1vVXZAIZvSYK7hH6ECQYoMgboLsgZ0AlByyyXex2dXQL3cJk02@eqSKCSqHIuzMuwe2FePiEQl2h5ZZ6F53bJIUVGNSwBRqeS0yCxRMD3pAQlFMFDUfyxFT1I2uNhJNdwz6lN83AswUWRJLsIhV8YABKEjAnCh9k1J21fXLl3LxBcNmo1aGwgTQHb7CWjGm0wYSkDp4bIMkkjfibyxDmeYN9IJKG8GPmKYwNiE7TUWp1dTIYu9Dh6vxIgEpBVsLElB4T16/lT83Tau17RNnpiJBF7HQhNZnciVgUY/HlvqN1G1fgSVUHrjSNVsfFiegJ9o/GSL1ao6EdzDQ/F35qPSqSGE4iB31ZXkogn9f0WDXp/3rV8kYC7oLNzbtQB9E/9iayQEaV9mSDotDd6KgeC3YHDYU/3Th7V/L7IA5WOaVeWPCynq1vkvYnRxSDt48P7z/ae/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@EH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8@jZ166TBCQhJAflAG78XRNpeBwQuoSO7g2vDcJskEpBlmGSIC6TDlkAM3Qg6hiuB/g8nb55g5V3Hamx74@YWVOdAwg8lUM7SCdj4DUBLAjq9PmISGlBCjVtXGhYuKIxA3w@Rqn5OjIkSkeazMdHDw@e1QisP68mURTFm4Aspbs9Gdq8NQUVfFUcYH/g6rKUvEAc5WnCdSWBu90lAi/qlq2BDwBQ15EdJlmjoGjeEHDfv1428pW6YQugd4JwXa6MykPdD0U0ggcOcV1UeVeNohSwGKxCr5UjVhi6PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs9eFCgtCsA4EMiNLgSdehL6yAsp0herffSPH99A3CMhElQBKcDMs5hMeXmWgNqLZLK4p@yDhuZYhvw5cTyRiUlFiQfrAnLXI@UzEv9gZk4SmSR/qkmIC7nv7R1qD4LI/pQ1zWSQ0oC6OI5Mbh/X97oetBHbsZyBw7YgDZcOgwxBbFpbzL2BY9@oIR09sagxXCIE/osTN/oYxhrzDSmOlCqqrvLFRt32zoFLq4UsEokoRKAUii@/0s90INei3MeH3ziAQUTNZzKhO0MXkCCShsiFrm7ElzyYBBnJPj4rCxguF97o7UGAFFmvw0L7jC5MuLcIXulJHFNWVsZfidInzg2Kv3Lm15oW@PCmBY4IyQ4/ffr48NODJ3tfNCdaPr/0nsuUC0A4yK8DspA85HTD3rrFuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyR2BNq@ELrYlPnKEd95LXC3OOodIru8ub0BPsfDyqnxAU7Z6FyojLV6txPMf2M5xMxl5FUaCXD6cdGZRW5VXXsfSBQulgYLAsRUXV5fAI5zW8VSkAGW9u8BR8cgtEhznNIOrWyAHlhda8kTWwBAdPs1aWORiCLowL44ablMMWTKVReqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1WtxNu1mtFyihhEW@r@EHejb4DqlIDRCkiRvPbKmvea99gcuDRCug4kxuQtmuTwGI4FFgNBkmZNUc8PiEPcAudLkVcQjV5PcTYXuJSSz@SKaiGvgFoGahrIrBLOuUkjfdIdShNHAniS06d5g0gr7Htd3e7LW74jQBbkvo@gqNnGi2bTboGA3rxHuOG6c2PeaqitZJXdTLLlx09WofUuFQ/bbuABbZec0DTpydbws55@k531dOpdPaZMRmN/zJHG7MkeCFJvHODXPSPa9zCBEg1UtpbiKhj5rbJiQsjCpALekFIKdCgYaaHpKYiXBEIviofQcoBvRRKwxWwGLwff3xHhI6h0Y7s3nbhHayQo1@BsqTcGItJkcxe5tIfzgxMYHcOWj1waKheZNDs34jiPrnt8thIS@Wv8QXrQ1UIINCsfzkjb4a4GaASUitRz4BzQrnDadLiYZUSlH1oaZEg44eQDSBA2rR4MgM9AYl6QPV4QnhP5LBfp1HbObYTWMVhJ6pgTPtnvTF1c6zZ70bJB9KzG4wA0KlyEr9OieMfo8llWnphKAUqgzkbGyMGpBJCuiBUYVASdL6ijLujhjDV0q4yEK4YAX2K7@8DFugafL5JGqERBkzpg8Ymr7EnfUHTpDbTmW2QrLHykiv1KPwkIsLy9gWZJ/BlQkk6cEUX6nOZbMPB@IO4KuGIIJYYWJuo1Z2zY13U@rhEmklXahhCP80Wgi/jGxka8Eq/H0@DaAdc2unbQlQLXDrkkcmE8GV2UIk0uDG1QCvRrxa8aAeRZsoVtYIaSwxtznNAblUq2ldYbqv/U8JmEqgDKQ2wJHwAnnqzV0JlMivVzXLMB@T1S9n1sO8dd1xz7JPgEBAL@7tMgS0QA9R6ledeoom56O0VGNReURgNFzIQbbzYyzVbzotlLNa/iaUydrOo10A@BeU0SI3ngOtMxCG6NXEUC3pZsZCutaqcWz8S3EomSZEFGejL5USmZ0jmtE3ED2lSi2YwDSX3qNLpDl@DN0loyGRIK8OiboGVYViIuX5Qg/06ylUzFIW0ynga2XIvHgS604OhRoXFGgDeih@YMSAkdE4a46JoCMUhanMLu@g1jPJy70QjhrBtI2TiDvtirglt6kItHueQbnj4q0C1p@oHcy@OBcIuTdygvjeecuwsc06aytDMqGHfPpP7ImejKZzIoTXJkuIxvxBVJgpGQQjgkKvYT08MurNuGM/WiM40rJ0Axd/A9GU6BWQbb09LQqsyxYHSHDotv7gJ0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16UOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8aDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSR5ZvQEC/hHH9ijzOvCNXrKlkCrtI47hBECSoOcWAtra@QHKI437smTGSQVEjjgRgO5dgdC5znraZpW6Ob7lSAMWwUQewiVhFqpDSpuECSpEJj0K/mATwsFOvqnRw8O@NwJDbY4vOI8Wnvk9KYgV/p60zPDHqTZAbQn03ZGJpAhSP/m1HrmOBOu5cPLupkZrjSbo6ml05zP9WmZW9N1nY5j0VTQbUkX8aeup1s6n4QKQvc@ewKy/vOT45pciURS9LPRrXnjPOTqbDk9D6NrjrTeGiwPebxhipt5EcetYNcnshk/oIABU3/PJ9RR4F9E/6BL4RqK719C/xHu9wRZ2Z9FoNfQ049Ypoi4BxQ3vPmeF2rmCv3X6mBhPJXiccFxge2FqpH/2aTfX/LOkvephKzJWnjnyJvvBV3SEaMo5Xkk3Bi6FCcKqEBxwv2ha@MVKR7f3SKHK4tPwk0IQ8MKlhafgcSCy2cw6FsoV4HSgiI638NpgIQ9xlUSYt249sa6IIR6N@YzoLONJR5biG1QB4LBTUGRRthUmD/3XaUuZDv@mqXH2aoDOj9Nq2zX@So36lQuV@cUPiu/2QYQ2/VqsOFuXTTMKR4PoxFUwg1SUDFpYf9GUcNtGh5NtguUpCp4CqgTMy0jNWfFg9ZlXPGIDH0mNpuzjzLaF6CX4G7JzXvKwKjSHqc19KoGIXFfhu3MmQQSH8biE9fdIfAZlpotkxLqZ2r3Hasn8VUyaDCM61dYQf4mhXAXp79Z1zDdYAMn7aDlSZG/RvZ@3oB7rUrrNyNEdouGgKD7XLDL0/TZJWvAkHcme2PLnLTYlTxx2kN/p5R9fV8pl0FdV597gr/Hpcb2nn38WSPT4hCEkY4rXyVei7NgezIIziAo4T5ycOFOnYk5IUmAdiKYWF5VBqRmtEgC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULUL43LRVn6BmiqCQMx9@ajNDOSV3Lf0icTw@Ztji8/ric3Xyfys6lR9jv@okOFZWhlBiRTE8MAxSo7Pnlw8OyZDC3XS8QPcAWnAt1R7w5BQFlX6ICS0cJX2Ee9OPsI0yRRbRegq4H20fbTQ6OuQqMH/QNyR94xMNwEeCZx8aUL3rTeRQm5hOYTCPdbdSdEoxBYwkhCmQhYZSX@z22uavl4VqDFp4iSQO7EvQrQ1kzKU9t8LXsw0JDcClHiXFmF8aK2mSAutqkm/Q11I1w6Bg2LhEYoQaPBpDfA5SCyyFqtKt8DAHFRAXMHSF1RpKqgXew1Naj6GniDSEMQ/OS1t@xFIyOVW6nNVaBoc5m/AZ2XPwIXISyD9oyV2W4mqL/f6MgcB74WyDn3c1Knr52@qLBN7hD5nDNFDzZMEdOh/VXL@6SWd2FBJ0NWQlMxWJCAJcT84wF@m6Vw4vyg82Ay8kgk2UVIdA1Jzi4viYZsU2NEQ3CpjFfGVaB9AmN67EBpHvtHA6LSAfVWfyMJ9tmmIAZq1vJKLYZwEV45uyadSmdiNB2XDk371KH1ntDVzshqHiXCMPXo1LqZEjeh0m0paogDj6utw84bdfp0WxGBlj38BXXyoAl1XxYGIVJXntGD5tZX5Ly8iWQpW397Ko204GbS6ztiSuUSRe53Oua6qEAE3BcWPFdEAyaF7VmTc7IanDXAqRgYj4Bxce1lUfTr@4/YEt39fbT@8z9/swf0v1k7QxgocOYxdLRh6MaakvprK8tPii90W12xfIJ8apk6EYZcd4Hs6i4USbdCx2rQtAgvSTD8j3BJwa9xaJt4A6nxlmbGMecrgsFzdSarFtVsYJnddXGv7cfiWdHyDyh2PSICF4JMgxIR6@KVYMz4EkxExUY2djdSwaYpRo2Z1/twOpnyOwiud1aiOcbfbX3Tj5nJ6x3VUPjO9Vuq3NVPpz1HGp8OQjm1sCLuovS0BiyBOOAvB7fRubr4vIB8J3jwXBdtMbQp5/S4q1V49tQbSx3Swnv8jTrC6JYcXIvf10Ux/cN7oWM91UyLbu/ZEn3o0FD83RAK7jWVIkQzr5HZ0jtzlEGGH97Kwp0FwHFq3VQqk12ztDwer0@PmiSlL5dXp57JXU6PVXMECt/PKvFZNCqwv8P1jlqF4coc6Zak9SLOtcx81caEG1HDNU1Kg4cv6ATGrY0cB6Tu1NLdheuWJr7AI1hGWDcj7Q8bT82uA@LAmKlFWdWCoSMyYBDLDLbGLTLC7cR0i2x/MFeRMThOIoWu1SzA6U5wy@iaNvUeDI1v1cQNsZFGIjvrKNV1zvG3VnwYgmrK76tHtDcrsXoP5iRZXUuHcXztcLA0OYiTj3c01HPTM@i2mrCnKxGddK2V/stdIJj2i07j3dWsPdNyPHZM99sINHCBCvy@ukFHaWnqtkST4VH3LTwo2OOwqFDdGjhWoTRQdLitrfWp20e@7z/fl8OFHEpV7@BQgfjj2Kr/XMvXTxX39K4KogOLLu5vjThvGWJXsSl/7WV96UAxwIW71SV7mClRSlnhU31rMsYll3N9Hjx/hqFjHWmDoWM8J3EapDtMUC6BY@JyEftnyS13e26992NKN8AW7ypEpHJPLQMGK7rfqFKmZdQPTKFmMu/PovrW1JgaKxWNo84rA4/V36JkvD9SGb8Ym/5MPS4O4NGUMNYbXzN8L6xxnMa3W5mJbpld425RZpmpjUH6HqPq/BQcT9FxM8XAno6XanVJO7Of3U6y4Tjo0k5vCTsM@VA@VLpDUlqSzz2DfrdqTFzDww1itXwmk/EFmMiKy9LLbZpUNkz7yuT3pYzJZ5HzIi6usrkR5@o8iCzRLYhrWZC2TrGnyOWyYpu2MZnj/T25acdxrA@pKWCqeGDYAW1Voq22t9XYDXHHP0TCFlMXHk54dPrrJi34aOPrlkAfVJpvq/ToktB71aaEi54jXJBafr19@iaywHRXLni4FeeE@OZba70s6c@GqHJJLt7a67iE6nQMS@ePWSF3G7yynL0V3jLT8BdrcXGXL@kuluJj15jSeA7EMnugpQyNkUGvt0j5eg9NZPiPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vMDozuughjE/iCjfelNeSIsDRxbNCvJrjPD/UUC3eS@r7rOHCw6reSyIcjfWBwmy23ccrFhAXupuFq3cK5euqiwnfQdCHZwhjH@iYBnerUmHvBcyXAJ/Mu1Ot0dPd027XO38U50Pfo7eu2sN4cYu2hM7SHxpDvGw/f1nUOaI8TbmPnNtQB68EQt7KNx0tb3KP0tBzLeh96ImvkjNJx@itxOsDDr3hy64Pg8pP2/uPOyTt9wnkHOtb2mqExhXHJcybO2JDobV1UCyd6@H0dDw0WqX/WGaRb9XygSPD8WeHfqVsOdGcyHtOjPbamHt0oqURnlu@Sm/p8awptinTcgfzGGXVk31P2963QEvhqFtMxJ90hHhrnLdsYOJ3u0LwLad9QhRJM@fDX99JdkTImkx6gt2yZQF53LmN7qUXDj/FxuK7S/dkjPqyFjlvklVUzdHQsWxrrp12Pz4aii1VwQjjSG/nh7Qodf6@8npqTBdDIXqZwepcvS6BjHe7@7om1khWdkViwYX9XxdpWSkI6CuSSkQGBR12X7fI@t0gXy2b5bR1C0VISRpF9KR9Cbn/vD80OmpF5W/Bfal9Lm5ZWDnL2cDrwbjJMPl3fAxENb@unLWgvc2TKGsYs3fYf68isWQoecoRnG2SuqXHrmkr@1kUViqdaku6Y8GjDA6puunYOzTLHHr8zqb92Kc7fywS6@PX1Qk6b@Wpl2q@YntHnSyDouktEHDku7kQGGUTq4ko6zqAjM@eCF2dctjMApi5ZbBE5iLtObFm5TWh19YdjpvTFp8ZAx73Wj80JbtZc0Sqoya7aXnQn7K9Pdc/8@hRKtq6xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeE/0gdl9tFQRIZI@gf2dnvyx1PzR62ZdnA9ND3c0hY5bJqawyfFGjK2uDXrDipjX5@1DYxWLDsSPQa6MvWpu3RnP8bTYnFy3TaubE5pl9Z/rVMd1m8BuReJ8OhpPPf@xGgfaMxWdhR6dkr93bgJw6TWwVjbUrcnqmerIlCtIYf6guHCuk8a/YVrOgH2jlGEgtIEQhsL5ioZzH4bnp7ghx7VXtETK@z2XPXGiQ3J5wV5D3RpZJpm2Obl9Nmcywc05wRMLw0cOPKGgPMa7vPuhEKST1RR5fLesvziafMf4Di3v2Jm6XQOdob2RqFrg52rsB7uP8USHg/ZSzqNaWtexoHuBw1rZZbqOPZ1I7tS@dVQo3DoqVNDaVKQZsMTXD548T0ZbA@3WvksKDeyRLVxrNwxca2SmDYLYej66HDvQJR5wO0nPaKvwHWn20JhTl9j1A2eVvvN0DgPIeytMwPynowdGF5cN78z7U@eJYzswGo2BUY6eGfzM/9JGj9UJMdljPNUO9Ondmc0xgV0zCHFpQx8bHahfa@F6n7GIA36gT/Q1QxHNDZL@F7rubCum1THcVzTpF3GvU2mXEXpkzEi3WN9geB@UJt0uF4lxPm6pjyyt2Hhjx7H5nbhtBh7qk9u5CgwFdHv/hXIZN@IvzQus1M@Wi3p0xneJGD1ulGJdWV2j41j8fsueJNvkewJ01zQ85THaOCC/Qo5JIH15t/KQ4q08ZKEagSR7pnu0SL9a1ViAVGcfsAVoqLtdB1fCfMctu3MihgnuYNPh3n6@caADhJ8Bx9K7U99Y6F1oWaPOiG5rFYZIbT4zOngqqEPWPCb67GZl8pkh35RBZEdXaAAgYFfYqQss8RS0keTdw9aSHrVMVXNMN@LUa5fLabOOZJtG942Os2YO0WsxN70UDmVWPiXnmrnqSDeiWWRFp5PuK3vS8tY1EGgsQ5oMXdD5lclt09uBmZUV6yHTkYGLzMurMGtFV8cbUmGd1evpIXN1Dcm39Qe8JLT7x@VDaW@t5Ing4f/o/icKDMLtQi4wPQKs6@4VfEB@6tr@431a4FPHm/TN2RHgjacA1rETLFYeksCD9wx0ba0rBNSePbX47MMgsu9q1CN1TCIrzJJkEbueGJJhn0lkCG52s0QOP/Sl7KH13onRk3w7CLjSID0Ozn@F0fznigXUKG/EzZ6qwgk7K@T87Z@riHsecAaQt5yJNPboqYy9p4ePj07ksaeuHJ/2hng64oYct2RYQStlIlNSr3Q3st7Jt6P1TG@i3D9Wpf3HhzJGWENvvqIhwQNX5pYea@c9Ayuuir5WC8JQY7JaQHx08uRxanFEkyX2h64zMpLR4P3j4zSeNPnkeGVwNPVD6B19Z7Y2@eGBqiZXNN/nNq0OruOeK3JaB@nEAG0UGuMjbpflTuGq64yN3sl8bHwGgydycO89sy@sLeSn@pk5wF7IymsJRR2VleVCLhnZmQ3KtuGGz3X1eWqOkVt26aHwx9rtKCg5ZBU3u1p6uG3F/7oUwzL@ToQPS6RmbrbWqB1hRff@voipqrqOzsd6H@qV5ddW1nKEVevDlnP2HkvJhq@8SKGXNIFWJZl37iMvSiNg3QrecHre9wRnZ@02mNsAhN6FlR3@3LDnui3RWtZt4kUFUuOmtlujfMN4jwWpcIfPGRorX7nGF26pZ4kuOZN3ZHziRpLs798/vCvBM5@Wt8f6@NPn7KnuoRGS2yNGMTbeA@OFZPRKwnkrtIC3djm15wIo7VZ4g/Hq/lxhx7rbc@z57O5FODqDikM7GRcOYeEbRTIsc2auGqu6fF7r6eptRnflzQ9xOPMlOThqnMYH9O7b/0xVMxkyPYRPNcNf76iZoIOzBLr0OdqziwadHIasoYtyiwweyZXa6GNjhttR@GzwKqV@5fhWuGXsKybXDye3hZVuCcvdkt@NMPRkWTmj3gIwf0sYy8th8GPHOh868r7uGt6K/ccrEbqtIOVbClKOcGffWjotLPru9SI@Hl3wHytb64kxcXPjodMxcyvLsNdHI5PsCRpLvxnub6fQXdreMnD8Ix/8fXV@51NjZUZP9DerA4jTnK4MAiZoDKd0JOJm8PICaQdkXsMemNy@IrvvTA7o7RbFLDzxvHovgjl@MB2vxxh4I36S4jo7X4r4OejMzrnH7uPRuIWYvkL3x/1xq/3XybQsnBhEM6OPTvaC1nV0rGiRHBdYfPF0yRsPj06OjiN@rjGbrVN6pdk6HXJlyCLXT09yS9lu11@crSDW@vNGIG4APw6fa@Ugzuw@Ob7JElB9G05GVhDyiW4vZkyXKqznTOik4crAp/MZbaNcWdNDvottVZjbXeG9pNjDgGyakLentNtoWb/dXtcqT4wvaO0BxCA24WIJB@obXjJmuWGAISVZ21Gd04Xws4Tu8Xho2rOVQaN1aWgXaeKVt7ob7LFjyzlnj0OrQuvYg7YauH5m2OuY06rDilI5e7sUlr0mUq2rF/71Ev@xrkrurxPUrvEM3BBxGzfB9M@6ysPg5TMteWf8T46D6HfH3bccnL/vmdPR3ZEJbCp1d0T3FvZ3HaB5dzT82Mfp0HHtu6MGzalSuW@8JxIb7x1zNO8674FDp9@/O9KB59wd6cnUmpios6yIyg9JQx@LGtj30r6JJG5UgB/l9uTgKwiJhA3Vl1z@5FT0XDqaoU5sohnWTTqDDnEvL9mGf@4bAsTgJLl/0h2tNZr21MCj6vxDNJPaJmRTq6n5MtvBbzxVQMtMUo7oRTbxgrwabPPCP8RdqahXbKPGxIrI/GP0oYlrbqYZ4KKBWSgTk05VtjmBkM3gCDijL46wS0YzV6Aqq/kMvMlK1BhG1T8kDyhtXjw9fHpwfLJ38vy4kWld@Yfog0LYNuQWmOr4KNsToew@2UAi5kbbyXiDBdnR11BwxssLysXwC0vLRastFW1RKHEH02xe2LaikB0BRboC/CSR50ahyNfBi8MOSkz145uQqPAj/WSZAKqIgxYpT6izCsusynisg3S3afvh1z9IRqH4wboKfrIOM/btbENDHDhOz8/RM9jdV5Djw73Dx8@fHbAAwUWjOTd7k2GtnOdm2LltE6invkkbK2ss7ieJQ13VavGHcSBMXI6zCll@IBPo0M4hWkAdtBnhp95iiU2CDxSMh5Wi/OdvKldxGc8IJCFuPEAqDtlCk6eGsrGxwU6gkbAHzw4/O3jGEP@DB@SNJEIQ7ASPnf/Zj3r8IyKBWajgY33uiEQxMqsjRE1PBPYYFiYjkObUdcfrP9lHH@0gwwzh10LCzx0JAn1MBtrtOVl0vGbtL0kGuPgnBn1jjEFG1ISCDw/gchQaVnQ9dmZ6JpqFQBz6aOdwubHjDjay7SmzPfweIX71UKcv2gDqU3vCbYn5FoVi0NLkkOWk2SYhy79/I0Yixrc3oLF3DJDSmWebIPNNKuwVtERc8qlwsyGSVI/fSBKArpBLQskuEvGGYURPabrKu1/9J8qgysA9Afd3fPcscx/eftl/64P7V7j7hYIN7aYhxQUuUYTQ@KlfAo5ISH@kfeQzjDY31bIgHNp7DPgqM0dQTWdEdYzOc@B3CdjxAk6i8RlUGjQ3qDHfRAvPz3BbCbS@WlEUbFKoOcp0QMaY8d2q16ywFvKFnKoAktJZAJA@mzDAY/gcYDJZgW4inJnj2kvQRra3t5mI00dGrVDlNats2i@y4ssQ0U2IK5wPEbkGgzSQZJECwup@Mhh8UmoSkyL3iqtxZFw9B0YlCsfRC99tnxAiSwCxOI0MtMM/wy92TkCo8q0Jd/Abl5FP6mz6gCQVxiRyJUXBN27yqTOB5gOddPHRLG7cBHdr8xEQzXR6/Du2ZMQX26N8s2ctzuQH3@7x@5qMPICDymauD6bRuhU/RxDHCKIirmq@jResOWnaLYW3TQbN9IcrGrMN7l9SBmvaLC/33k0TronrBliRWGz32HZwnuwhFIYlNEXLKmohuShSLreySH6J/GygOGgn6hKyAzYFLKNrmK@csbe3f3D4ydHT4xtmSilm/Ho04Pv17VRTktONVuiIR4u1XCX3HyrHT@4/DCpigXQhwo2B8fslUW8ryWL6G0EujlNdL9oqDK@Xbj3Gn3ODC9fxzWq3oUaJbuChZj4gXzrSID2kg4nXM9dKq6iVz9@G0gKeEgG9z0@V30A1kby4arS26007Fr/ZElZ0hBcxeQs7Abia3tamgo39ZuGwYOEXpk/w231etC9mV/dFcTOLVvDQqMXEOV3YCfQ9IgGR8gbZAIsUZCWIurb3HXEZfWHNUuNfwObm86LGwSIIFzK3UTwC6iT4mDZykYUtXt8M7VD3hpbZEQKjbNwcbWA1M7REyw2qJZKC/0UXnnHC/7z2rDKTaf9iIoncjmCl2W2WbQN4SQE6NEp3T6fekD11xtzCP@1TeWAErmcOsN8HUz6vZbBPpiOI16fHM4PWDIFzS5AYKBkPUeWyFHAJ37DtLIWmgyG/Bpq39Qsuj3r5xCwpD41ZzxwAb08k08DRPlLVFguN32KhyditHRepzha1cGtX/BhtBUTJ/kEWkGcLBPSGLpt2z5gl4ufxZKUF@aN//Pzzs3hSXNWWyBKzb5q4d90kc4h@Ub2dk@gTv3cG9o5XcYty@SaXAL/rgLlpwODzYuWyPPQE@lxkDSX344n7GJwgRiT6I33MElObm1WUGb0mmgk7TfbmpDo32WqzVIoUKnhQgMwoZZ9cfPxO6PacJZQaflEUfD27h4835pg1VFlugZsySbJN/OzfPkhcaGg0KYAODEkqBLaGTQjUDMCIdxKZN3BIg@EQFx5knHJFMH0FjZZWHKQJlZrV77HIZxyXJUexXK74FbrMFcsMWt9NdigrAPYGnwvkeqCub3EJaAbqryzEFoz8JseLUb4xjsgj31QToBOLmFkOLDgxgLUwgtwduvhLHNjQV0A@qFSenzxsl5KKyEKTTwPX7OHSH/9SQKji@d92gm6qLEWNV7lG9zEmQ@OabW5TCm08PqQOI15jqbEoGXwDxYGy7C3apqre2ur9hH4tQMwcDgD@0dh2AA4NogZzgivCVjP7n/40hsJGYlNVT9vuWSqez1ThplbzLM8@2mxK0mYjU9vd1EGLmryeNUEnV7ZyD86MYb93OFCaosiyLKcoWxcXF/GHW0/NF3lWkHqmVng9m19lC9nXs6usWnp9OlYLDfn1rCWWaunTFnv69Iu37bdJcXY2fy02E1ps/@hSVHOo8scqZXaxU8jGTsugfkK@jJ2yN3Cd9hn@k/tNL@LW0d3pgwobF1ms2QSKq2JRVJRGvAX/pO6/hIsr/o26XJd3Wm/fJhu6PpnNmWmaY6/Xg58zBAlSSx4z0JfvAafnCRTWpCdpUHiNZv2b8wl5xmZ7xmAwPdDrGp6alnfb1bk5fTh58o3Pg@s5Xm@eRZK98b8znEolJKmxYp6i0tbzMfxi8Z/9eOMqffG0vf1n3xopxgY@jvDxnasn6D5W8x9tbHx0/34ul9Y0jbuffuPpz@/t7eUepPNPG/mdnJTZ2P7TP9nY0LRtTdloeZ7aijdOT78QtUxOlP/sd@Ltp0@/7nn17P/5zbd1FW9FuJ2xIvAJuLJMBSfeS/BTUcZ63yv2JgatXI3N6a8dC/wvNpha3yn@l@8dvY5NYnVN@dyF5yT2OlYoxbgTHPCWDd7OYvXYNkYrXMXmSq1WA2fxv/xbSF//BOBgyHwbbvV8AKswj9WlGiW5jNUL4FA1DfL9v7/5zQiGnE3USIwLrl3WgEvMFTVxpwXXFl3bAprSlDKKEsSzJ8OJ4TC1dE@9hy8mvMDDNvCbBMakGcNvtrOjXcaeNVKpVEtuS3DJL2iSSFFVramq94AdSB9t1WrSFuPGQrPZ/D00eJ6kKa2BAyOmce/zf4grtsqz@jODeybEChu7Lx/U61CmbD27VU/R5Xck6lPFkug4uyJLs5dxUEEarZePGbdwXBczJU1Mp9O7bXqfIa2kWdiS8OL3WCz0wS7LrvstJYEovm/sw@PFDvD68//tz7//59@jv@/T7z@grVG7Z/aVLYh0Bl2iDtdupdKt18W6K1408b0O7ShTKVVKSvuqmdgCDtR6xtTMx5fxfDZ@zL@nrjLWTFJquCjbup89vtdjC@8696lH/fwAHpk8mF8KcixRjdwh1W7Eg6HV35UtNc7qLQkFoprUUAv5lsRT1YOrzBq7UE2iViyLrbqW147YbnvGLzbc9JgTA82wENDRx7e@KFs9DFm81aNesXqQrL6I86HxQnyFWKOhtAwaEAI/trtR2ShVChVNadfXX9A0o68U1TCMp17sLBZenLKxBUFjYdO87hdURfjCghbMPiQeSEbvw3yplrIFVaz6Lq3NxCo0Ei0raYO2mFHFsLfh/D5cG/BH/3CFr3jfIB/fm6LcvDZYRd3Sskr@o8KBhuPrHVcUVwHGCdbtdDpvuh2QOnS9o3d1daJP9Zk@1yedaWfWmXSnXYZdZnlGP@vknZIzY7wBylIsm1c3Y/eoUb9tbLBnnAu1WCq4mqk7r@ey3Pad5HDwJ0nOLCbE/gGuuqqpbAvGpwzcQCgjJ@jM@KeqAouBoHXRervVeLsFHbSe2ibm2KpLPpbwkNu7rZR0ddUAd7Xq/2/XQ2eVLu6CwrWuUqntF3WQPl7UGykA@cIHKUuMgMrtemubQsLM/Nz84O0WyC9SaruxXXP26SdTB5HiOSdecHZbAHh7Cdnd3ZQMrl0AUN@E/phMpTYlaQPHxoY/VkDkVj0VlApxSIC0cHHxM/5A0YNefLV9Vb9qbF9dbW/D/zbdr/wn@F5t3/inx@JaE2cR3kLW0mwo9abS9JlFC95lpY4@stIERx2eEK@R1UqtBjrgklv/bf7L6cU99EGUWzJgLcS22FYMLV9mY1tC7OW7L/8X/DXfffn7KC8y@DMqQuwCu7WyhdpmmSudcGP2E5s94ZcNbvwFr@iDHk/q6Gnzm40LUoryUmYVPuefUEuFpIwDcNvpt9GYhsxeQtQbvI@JWqkgtlPqXGOxbbFQJHb3czeueDz@j15q5WKcT9SgNYiXnuc9iWC5wBMiV7WMKqmXdf7BA/5tmp9bdf2jn1t3CbHLMjMqQJ@uxzhlhBg0pJiiSBKMWPXtEZ4XwLUSCdXSs9oX0vM9CedR9AmthHX5HEHt8KBWLtf5Ms/mU@o2Ww@24K7C/8EGlIM1@xC32a91RyABN/vZvNZE8/gxqfMa/x6/wT920sW/Z6/xj528wb9nE/xjTzr4d/Ia//Y6@Hcywr/7r/HvyRv8ez7Av@ZXslm1Km5eEGlSalm92pyJRKJqbKfe/MrEnVcsw26YvZb/5adsrsySseZXjFnXGE8q3LMf/8l3v/WteK0Wl@L0PZ2c6rhMTVaB@lAiL17djQuxGttUN9WMlelm1I7aAYfJMi7LDDNDtQeKSltlGYNl5pk5y4wctQcuA/4y4DIzfZYZsIydsSEihIJr0s5M0NWHxwD@@gDIhT8Tt7921EyXQUYWCm30KU4ED67LdlNosDgTXxqga8qqnJELZgs/YNQQX75sKlstrVxiMjYqud142Yy3xKaIRu21co515sZG86UIQ3NG5I0PfVjM80CBrcaUZlPhZAIKEBWvrtrtg08ftNsKDkPNJ87R4v/oaBR9vfV/dOQ8OXJGDvwfHR1B1zHqqd0UMOjd3RowbP@xE6tXd5oVYvsB648p2zvNelZCdyEF3FxDv9QHXguI8KxvNIX4eQJ1j3NUP6qfn1fPquQ@D17B0a4uIgTRuMN/wnUOQ1ygjpzDdXaODnpD5/nnzdDFHcrn5@D1OQO9K/wHBS/6@l/h3/xv6//Jc5ZkiUYrmbi42k7QlcS/ZPLi6uLKv9eTiYT/ktiGP/SAd0xycVVHJ0W6AFcjkWwlr664H9wTyW0OsA7ZbNcp7SIeDAuxMEvKlt8S/3WfkLV/NeNVkHu5bp3PUD@KiVWmL/bVNJuzTCZZ7QTf68BVYv2SNi8kq/Sxxs1OQ2396e/QN1l2khQpn6tW1S3GX7ScVq3mgrdiqVotBS@biUT55lXP7KgF0D9yuWSyWoWXnQBsBl4hbYO9TbEaa8K9de8ez6SkXV4GMLO5QiqjZjB1kFMesjU8vesz3IvDI/qcCbCafAy/I8RZSSJDH0PCD@7FxYp4716iZ@Ae697OXvLePa2cubwMfcZj8FKXvNrtnum22@ifvbwU2yLtgynn4T1TurxUM@WUGk86buJT/FIjZJWQVPaRVqdcy8DGtVwRgn0E8tvbhVy9XsiBT6EUT@KaegPRbwG@cTFeFWMXVAa1VOQcUKyid3R/EPRlHBTYxVWMKpTl8skEMNIkyIBXMfxzkefy4SafTwJlrkQeUy2XedQkyxUSpVTZ/6ttgFYOQg7/Q0ktm8ptFbd2QebFP2@26kKeXL0waupV7cKo4Kz6VbXrf/MaTYIY9@5ly0CiUqbaFNrtB3sne@12TRRFFJTghp7E3QW0lOLGG1TyfLnFKVKp7lI1q6U8g/rkcaQ4jBCsBERXtK28WkIiCWYfLf4ASQSuLW2wDUGjJ96EMqfcBniCOgOZ9@BiPdZhA7zYAJU3ZjKLLmYxHk73bjeM5PDLDw1fKS3pd4GPEV6C3wuzvInCIP708d7@wUla25ZYTHu4t5/Wjp/fj6n4ml@8U3AW358d7D04eg4Jnj4@2Ds@@Pjws4PnT8HfY@eLK2D6/n3xjLpWvJ@zz4VX7hvdMHRjahjt8@n0/DV7ZZptEyrTmkKhnIHLPKMNZRnri3JV4dc1Pf3VK90d08Xe/fDb737437377e@@@@1vv/vt7//ky@9/G34/gt93@fO7/6acx/tPvvxnv/vut34bPP8D/P4Ifj/@yZe//k3@o/c/ht9/ivj9sf@LxOM/AWD98k@@/N7v/OTLX/kB/P6l//vBzd@v/nj17/u/sP6H6b73u7fH@e6/hd/vcVhB3O/@FvfD5434v8Xj/coP3v2Lf8f//9T/Q@dvv/sXf4w3/@Wf/uBP/9O7b/17TSv96b9@9wvfe/cL33r3C9959wv/WHv36/9azURvv/vu@3/wV3/4e3/1h/8j/f@I7r/3Pv/vfvBP/@J//Yv//S/@0P/9GH7/Dlw//ot/D13lb//gh/j/vT/42z/6If7/z//qb//g1/72l/8ncvwGd/w///Lf8Ptf/@p//Jvf/M5f/fibf/NrP/6b3/iDv/o/fuX/@vX/@Nf//e//9T/5Fnr@xo//6o9@@S@/9e2//IV//pff@nLN/du33r98D/8v/wF83h/P94HzPuX6UJ8vfyZ8/j7UWOQC7QRa9y@9@/VfhAb@Lxh79@0f4WE6@K35/5GmUpwf8bf/Dzi0m2XGkAy44Pdr7779XSTR/wAkgv@QXt8JX5ZC@Mt3Fi9A1t9ckeiXfvLlP/8deosZlTqt2uDYXdJKqS3Qb7bKZX/89hd0IMkvLkMLAfg5fQc51FLYd5C3vfvhN9/9zj9@98PfePfDX8bBW8qV03tpSb1jNQwi5t8jHkYsvE88jPgF5p@iKTYp9QW8sS/8wC@@@EJoXyp4anP3Eny/IC9@MR6Epzr9oCAM/fGYJ7tkUbfvzPjOTd83zJmxxsuXLVxvBT/MPUWyx1YgGuWzbJbyEZsxvqyD/hBptkXOGd7JF4NnAt4W/wvnTGCpmT/dC8/UwkkOP52fBXcKecgmNQsXk0hWY1w62uI@tE5M@ebKDEswm6VmoASDA3JIQdB9EMdrtRQmrHF84JWjVi8xQiWVqkG5MTVPk26XEMTsPkGBlLXUM9beqs14whTCqwfkSAno9UxUNTFVqj2ADGuzBwxhIXAC@/JlrV6qzeoI7i2nR2qWuk84IbBaalZ/C@81ggnphNiDt4BKqZZK1UuYIRaSV0@6zSspT4WjsqdYyq8DeOJ2/51dxj4S1ZLIFwk2kGA8Nt5Ti9gYEaJDeDO15ReH/gMn/baI4BuUlZ8L4@E7JJvucHEVIwBcSZJlmcEP19932C4EzzioFGULjxSHkKIWQS0g9GA4P5QSUlS/KXqB/GO1rQ@@EBgWZnNzU4jVxax4JBPpFIW5pxU6@4DbAVG9qDCxUBbR26CDIAEukL5K@W/GcWEtzjhg9lGK/3Z3t9hHUEx6LvwEJqWyTs6JcSjbqZSoAfy6kxJegFoiQDslQJeCPKvRQl5KSKcZk2sxDGNHR0c@EuTxoiakoJlrWRXfcTlpOp3GIIUsp@V02n/K9CQP2XfIFOo/5U0kLn3KnGlargraU5WhF4uqOiqowOj59u1bqBXaX1U5BOWT@VuttFyJAsGDG6@xrHlwYEjLlQWumTO1kGMsQVOscCVZUmAJtpUU@K58jkRwJeJaqRSneEB9ObEV7LwrqNQccHo1VkdEg4urhKV8MgjcP2L7R0@eHHx6Mm61mGDQp9mN9th1uobnJTBs79MH/ESGVi4kY40Ggj6paMhghINKhpjx4YNnh8cVxgvtV0GCEKvSuqpfzLIqxMbjz7dj/s4jEb8u6IjHeK8sypbQyllIGqsLsa6BmgUumKMCXGVV4Yk3uO/MQKdPi2JaLaBml6RJZSb8vDNlaPuWG8qBPoXnNOTtbaKAUL@QaOkCnVBbBaFe9/fsMVWoHx@cQIKTI6ZqGVmof8FmMmYoXQl1q2YZ9mAy3MTNb2IzI0bKtNnIpPFPy2bhruYKaTVfbG1sWBcS5tmkarvAXYxX8HohYTG@ChcTviqwr4IXXJAHbk1k/r7Qw6OqvzkPrcwl@A49Uc1DN0sKOI/NwQnj6FWF1r28ECTENr7xjQmr10G/lg4fCjHgFkMW7E@TzJ48lKmae1PXoNABYz3zMxM/Gyn3TG9s6XPoOkCN2NXVVR8gHT5kWl2jV56ih/erLvl0wH0104WYXanU3qq5oqCdVipvs5omgIewpeAGuA1oALSPYEvhf1UPMslmSwpwKlUU4ZHNZgWcOxaEiiEw2ivyNlOrSbwNZnMqbRUR8Esk@qymhZcfd/bRIm42w@NiCASwwcRlmSCsyMP8t4JAb0A03B1H372u@p0zc@9eFicxsrlMOFtBJWZXUDeb2VwWKS78/xcewOKrOdvjejajbitjcOrgzG0rOjg74MxvKx1wmuAsbysmOKf1rJrZVqZ1gQnb3M4sQzM2NXFizNCsNfcT655h9WU8W1QTKQNN3PbttteDhPVered06aP11Z5s2rbh4qFzniCXE6uOjRYQa2gLhY7ps0TyQhjUzulovGDUBjIa1XFt3RJ6csfpzWVvMrfwlI7luLU4iIPxIGAB3QA5BOe@drLZXKXBWvLYGe8IWr6YaqgZGEDwp5bSWnrD2CkWKz25axm6u5Ov5EvpHh4A8pe4dvKZykD@4snjR5PJ@JlBp4J2cmVIgGbo0GDUTqmSz7caDVFMNSibFn5ym7MnaWMD@rSh9yR44gKYJ2mlFiTumW6tFo/vZFVNUivZTOlKWBAOaY4lrAuYNIUlSyPdL3wOULEdG5hNJa2nzQuiQqXf719tXaQWL4J@IfE3oM@VpKc7F@FrVYrEq7BpWjIXgeCj94HcF/7aXkXU8iWx2qgu3osFsdq6EnZHRs/U8TBQM3NxM1UBmDKHGoOMmky4qriOM6l0jL7jGouIWbUQROQI3YyQE6/C7JoZzPHiZnaFSKTZxU0oubx4FaYK0BKuroDunNhAdt@IcJ02zTbUcq51ACwIms92YF8Yo8VevBBiW88@y9brUNUXuaKWy@fyWrZQyBc1GG/KuUK@BJ0tU8jkNQ2g5MqlcvEK2rWivI3R5wPZ/kXQ3iv0AYWEXuEWQBstlnz7qWldlLISxyORrF5dxd4KsY@efabBALn2SsCg@5km1WvZfBlcWXRpWUCYCZomaVkpq0pqFv/vcGj4//7xNfjX8A6psppwgmaBPoVhE4Z6mz1G8yITh504@IGpAbtvdNfE2B/qtKN533U87@8R575un/KgBya3xRsGPdLxK3veyJwM18R4Ph6hRSHD/QeDcDDqAILIDnmE@3BzLcdZFaHInj9dU8onofV7IAY3fw/Rnx1@/Ogk8jw52Nt/JBTY/aNPH1x75P1Iefb44OFJ@FrkoUHSfAji5w8eP77@6j9yR8@f9aeOiz/h4dHz3OIWeuGBWSEH13Kk0JuA@Dd8JcESJApQxPLFwKEKeMziHijH93xnvrBwZtD5OT8NbHrhtn9@MLwinARHhHWGnLZjsC43HIXaOhl19GV5tVgWhDGznXNWzLCeY1m6y5x@fwM8hzoedzRQoLUsbImY9bnjWr1zs2dsCE/wZGVZxc@zIxLCIwAymnbJIAgIM2giGEY1m@GyVMeaGmw6Zms94YFe6HTNwRDG4HMniCB0dJ3B70MvSG9Er8ntHhOeB/ndCLFuRhdiwm6slBfFfVF8pE/0etU1ii@qXqZSuXdPjcefumJZHMPArHsD42AGbZc9h76ku/O0OJHFh0xuxwa4vmE5Y9REvHEDRPey1mjt5LR6KZPPlv76N3/0d3/ya4Oa2szsZ6TtnSePnQl7W0zlK8DoQKZlJLb6oq1MSo5WLuVL5axWSpfKpVxeLeTzaVVLg35YLIOKkFFLaqGUL6vpUq4MMkmuDKH5ctEXjJVAEla2KgDW7uLHw7dJT5KHoBDxRUn2JqEnWUwP36dMNCCNKKBKOqGD5FtmDYZTpmZYtsgAos66LPbw4X7m4UNRvI8vuKljPyOKPXzJlzKZ4n1RNChkv4TylejwNCU0wyhO@Esmcx/oPeUA8AsGojjEl4MCTq6Jookv@3sPH2I@fXzRMD1EO@Uh/MUKXooQzcYXkNcJwOsQGkTb4/nkCNEDfMEsMeQhD9mHMFH8OEAHQ57xaBzAo6Cke3uieMhf9vYwZJ@KneeIfg1f9ugSRRdeoCOI4gAcAxe6oCh2wIndQRS74OrOdfDDD7WjkXt7oovinJMHCSSKM4qtd09FsR34Yzaf@djkkboVelF5qXfppYx/oqgFSGO0bPiSFcVc@JKDsj169Jk@nPSMAb/mLn92oaSPHmV1czY9eNj5@OPOYNBx53sHHz/DoP39RyCbzKduZ9DxE3bacDmQav@Rpp@O5tcvKPVhu13RrZVBX2u3c7p9Lag9bxuIIaR6DZj51wAzGrX3IWj/UXtXX7WoTADbyAlG8OzgdX8Ez/t6hwcFFwXRc9bpiFVs/orSTAioPeByMHbHU@Csdnqkd12niu@zGsukUYCZNwqZVpUC2Ai0gEz1CsP7CbzrOBOUvJg3ZrVMqzarFTW@K6mfEJszLW@K6Y3RjlrOVzb0HVXLpWYVtGXh9OMsLqk7LKHe23rDEp8mdzTQCMTmzo4kNtTWjqaWKoXii62pKCYreN/JFitvEpl4hjG8JRvF1k4xH0lRLKZ0RasUiyCXAU0mMLx3cIKmnUicG/ppMonY0nQBFIHKyuZUTrPaT8zSsxrHi82T1VlNrXLjzixzA1gPvyQw7U4cl4McALjZTqaC6/EJUS2XREBAURLJZMj0QHsXFhtCP//6yenJyRckANb9mYynroHcq@q/fvxoXz48Ct7wGwDyQ5RLHVfeR661FMIF1MDrBDQS@REMqaDdBX54ZtB1LPmA9tGBcBsEBGaIZN8er3zyaAnO8dA55zmjyYUqGXW0uwbDTySYPabX6uDSeyxBWDE9eU6Debter7VrI7JKAEUMUn2N0fcDFmAOPY57aAiCkl/gOTo/oF3LXFU7tVlsBnDaNSapL0dO76WW6lZ7@GWE@7X7mLjahmenatQM13VcEXRrsdrfsWtT29P7xlPDRRMnh0ebIFrg4bpEnxnJTdY8wNj7qLdcSXWX2QvMPp2OErpU7ySXvXCWLvRA4iS@HhT6gs574o6Nq2q/xhIvIOpreHc3WaIn30/u5KpAp/usnQSvzMv@yz7TWCFXJb0jgbCgKxF9sNw6S9bqX4MHh31aqQA2fkWfAlTMDACbPQqA2GPzqtqtWSwhsRlLEpFy1UGtgckv8bYtiWJLkhqXLaEuSZ8Ldeiv1XlMr3nTDn1Uh2U6qpYpVGfgpxZz1SFUr/5iVnVr46lrVC149Sf3@NFWvQpEBdoBmDeXiXe/@M3ktpSvcb8qgbq0QAxpy@3arGqjmU5oGLVsDQJSjVwmDRo93IppGPO1QlotpLPpXFoqoi8M@Ol8GjxB4wExI2ElRMbEdGaWkdW0aqjpROal2XuZTJ8mQIAhorFkeuIc2NMRAx@oKmyb9ApPIE9K27JAE@s5TN@WqLECy6hiwYDqQzY200ME9czQLUqRTEosu5WwNhMYZ/NkOj5otCqVg9n46xCUkF7vFFLFTOpNMllNbCRrnvFaqFeFOrIXKvV4A1quP@/JvOmoAbUMLrWoVRqNDhaxmElnM1kondm@HGyLdbGVzmwUVKiiK0Zsg3G@EZ0KRIln4TduoyRuGVB1almrCjLNy2VLmlRW8lv5DJ8b5CmFsc/ekJIs0RSDY9yJeLyoxePJeBVXJTZEfxoaeBrxszhw1/g9dUcEYUysiGUNIyxYI53UzQTYgTh2JaBsyHKg6F4IVxdX23XhK8Ixnr/c1l7gX/HFk70j/PsKeJXhtfTiyfOj50cPBabQxk8QNKsbVbnarsKLJNd3hViFMeCkTd/GlLLB2IduKU1t11/wZxPPEgBcgUxvN1iLtnoZJmpx7DO0X7DD4lAG3R01NC3bamhFGPuAmwZRNU2totWmGJ5WkOsKnU7LFbN0Ok2IzS4A2e0U@X@Nzed6SgrmAe6x3UFqk5@2KYvbmK7gp@NLaJuY6Kx9FmO4Lf1F9ax6milvC0Tc2LX969W92t7g2V6VidliUazu7bfBKSZYrCrmfaDV3KP4s/hJ/DC@nayLpQL5lndx@nv1REUdpKvTU9U/EVTMtMVqjLXFvH/0LnJsKCdul5uCKOJ@u9hFPBa/gr8Fii/eBKeKCgDjNLP9AvhhLEQnGQuy0NriC@ZVTyU1sw1NZpeOVmr8aCWLhYcrceXYX/TJ5gosWQ7WZL4S343F43Fc/Kgw7214bs8Hr8bbYj3GMqp0Wo1tM7EUUOZN5rQqFgv@W1nM@UWklhwcdvvaSw06Ucx2Ag/QKXG@Dwb5fB5XGGLKy7H3Da2UfXJ4ZD9wH0YOXr3AbCFfPENWrbxob5yq0HmyYvY0HWO7MTp3IJYhV417AKFPmVp9gQRn4vMHR0/EHBKposbBKwFl4bhCps2Nyw0Hl5RYuNHxrf3J1xkbx7O5OGPNWmxWy/k76NV6XVK3NbRwV2QVGCr7akHKXNY5M6hTQEGDkHe/@IPcbLsE71pGhXdNy6e0el3d0lgyNn735e@jsaKLg8/2HrM4LkT83Z/8jlb8uz/5V7RXL35FixNathiDmOhUC8XYxcX44uIKLh6Wj7ViHKlcMQluvlCmxuqKqmVt266yiqLrW8VUTtu1q4ofVy2qyZgnxfztqdlCXkokVAWw2sqWMkkIu/RjapkSvAVLdDy6WICKggIcPDPzmrq7vQPl28nmtOoGtDM1PMLLwr9twyvHhFjpyctLxuClW@8NBqZGLkVhlbcS234rbbO3uED2VtpgL2t13Gih4sHfYAFpCw9C4iJqvJ5StuIMVEtWb1xVr1opWoEChfyFYWzZzWv9r7mBJ2GWvbZs@DO2PPrDRIGHB6/Bm7H1yhMTW0lF6fXEm/1622D5OjSYLWVxPJltBetK/E@Smsl3v/jrmlb4uz/51cv2ZfsLDdTzcrmgarGf/nR7ak89o1f/KQC4xVBNoGKTlI0WZdARquaMGz01/VShQ@6KQmxqoxrC4weKOqrmDEQ4c2AbPVLUhTMUO6ly29xWYi9B0bbQjkWa1BiyTZasCkIg73M1xR100wSDbaGl3kYrKVwIX8UgkGoYqDpV4asLUOAxAjnG6bY9a@qO6SRRgtKprTS7B0kgh6@iGcoNsr/hD4mSWmXK1s2kHGWPqEYiKhsZnodGLWE0F74KSXxz5tacjXU0FYMxTRvGYBmjEJ4U0GtA3i3I2@IJ2uSboNLzCGnGseOJbFBlhK@CVEZUMEFYY@Y2RKgC//oqEADKkPABmy22zbJJdmGmUtWFxcwrPPOANj31wEyFgMkQWg/NogSJqxgPvECFwg/oYrvwaxhk5YhnAITD4FskaqCEYXJ6Q/mX7Mi8NyiARTbbElQ0du/eAqtazewlGZUI4Z@aY5xQpHqwV@MKwAIF9qNeRUwztEVaDXzDZgcUTxG60OokboS0GknKRHy9EgT4f@9Giy3yWlVRQBUL4NcX7xVdIBkkRrLzOuyy7RpTtWKShch3AfcuIUXGAkKtvDn7SNa@CAKvAMOfxoLPUwHTOolO0vrt9rqdEgY6yxS/DYTW6jgz8O2LcHt0yPwOJ0HqMBUUxbQodt90QV@kvRuBKcxEVk1isoXpUMKD@LiWY3g4IJ/EB6XC2AyeOpp09PPZIFNUXQcq1Bs7NtmAJBtVeDIDWgTwKN98Hkd7ap/jt@T8uqHEUYw8Mp2HLR8xJpuWDhr7obS4eaLjGvppQJs0MwYy6456TCuzBDU0MvNnh@CSlIgQ7oDagTTuWMYIUDo2DDrO51UUZQCi6LRDtg6fmNCuhg9NGIFsT3nACaycm6emcoJGnSWnj6f@uOWYGEqv2P34Pg3frqDlOKfMMk8NPveeWLK74zFQvEB3SANlFz8gbAU3AGnZNM7/qGkeC35FeBS5s5SOpN1IzJM3n1l1I9HGGr2k8caEWrGMM92O0JeuS8GfcfDmXmC5i@xPwbscslzDt9lTi6M1jtAYleDbIKuR@SsZ13TGCTEmBra70CmMXeOM4dyBgGMMMM1uYAUHezGU9qs0AFDfg56FJj0nbgVtNwEmbi/Rha7nM3ibfcSymoARuWE13wgawMCqry1DhzBIiuXwJj2oGJkWMpCvQO8c9SAMrYb4zQ/TB60b3WRuddG82YYPDgcdyqvGeLcIXvKRF@wd2J6p6BsQWAAMV2CykRBTADYlJkUOOkx/PTlv7QLxkgq7CSnNEIJPaoBCooKOLAdtNkY@@iZAwH3d418G8Q1@np@fy2SFduqasuHhh9A8x9YtZTwwQfR2lIkxGvufnDa7yjiAu3BJ/PuH8ng43pmhdFsr35vzpyD0vZq/jSoR73txHBzP8DtfgxFZrENTcR41qIcmfSOwm/B3dfH2p7XSF0H7q2D7k0rxKwQC2hqAmaXn6W4agKU73dN0/7xX9QPOqEMCcKhFI/BE29Bu8DLyApc57ocxnAny0TCoY53SyjhAEvlE@SJrXsIg5jx49d/H5gwS2cY523NdfZ6g8CTGxgacmJPYw@Yw7FMIONFq@gU3VGzOGvPWUvJZmBwGtXBfiIvm6ISL24Fyq9UYPuPhMwif8fDZItMg28asxUUy9LrC4mCrRyumQUwEMw/iXHELz4sQggzyOKhU5Icx50t@V/Dr1ih1QG/@BvVYCxoGtIkxENxIKI0XzUazZXvG@VYrpQygsYtECKhxAN1oEU3Pe6EbqW@dWWPHW/Ky0XgtjEo@3ujVHfqtgbcVLGNYQdQwOL1MtDc6GPkbWLhA4BcYIKAcBoEoGuxNEmayGlpJp0BoOA1xQWOOWMNHpkXSlx/k@4G4xEnPCRsF1IoAQv@wSIAmhLCg5/DPXgbc4XPXgThBXIm@1DdCu3fxVhwoea2rcF5TpUqKYCVJAZpAdhRXa9eLEoRDVTSuBUWKeeXXfxT9jQ9Gvw/9YjX21GD5gFEVol0F94yCCOF3F6Iqq9ci9QoYKFu6Zbgwch1w@dQfrSGbLSVQM3g@WATv3Jx0h4lI5XeTvH7oZKpoi5WwKcxrNSjivMa7Je8XAUk5wcNknp9sHjQEPz1nIAAjszKZ4SebRZPNajXOONhsTbLzCJIzQnLGk/DYszVItvxkoD0dBsMLVk8LpFPc1CoCPJUPoyAGjUXm6WcGbjN4hTY5cXHGz3PBc6gV@G0IRWxsZ93WytwbEaQjTOsaAGyINwD0@Be0K8J1hqdK4VvIozgpAx7F3/xmwHkFNDBiwVVutzoRNjLSgUHgF1M0DkDfFVMNQVRpgh3/MvwnpgPP4Kfe9Mwsx1SXPTPpa3//IJ4tpGykg0akDzWTQ4aMmsxz2zf4GpU5YmxvCgoOSHWdc4clVgjb4K9M/aRKx3I6ykjH7UL4XV3uK4/nyUB/wCUqtjt2JvrEyeUqXGkyqdmtyp/rDObAdvBzXBHb9SDr9RzDs@MTqNSuM7BNz0gzNCt6avhqh@F/TEOIysm@0/EEwd@4xtVYBM3bFYq67bZpm5N2O4H7QZOVcHM7bQ/F5hmPC6j/giuSHtiTD/RonHA6r4zuJHk3TPwQg5/sxOyeJo7GfiDOz@4x4GFdkP8hdAgSDPOcheZIRt5RlO5MEvQBkaEzcgYg9U09WcDU18AfLmAjQvp4TLikmY4qbSXyOQ7qJYluWk/6Sb/2wUnZ17SEngzTa8sAloiRZu51GiNl3RXZtddmx5MF@R1/OL7HUXyPb8eXtPDrOHPVvMYDPyzrbGIBASIu0MjejQYWHfhW7wY6S6iE3ihX8QTvjWKPtuP1ENM9iLrnR5f70D7S4ZsHbyHin62j/@0VGCQ/eN/q06Hbs@M58JsR7mxN0BcUvWClOQHRD5PIe25mFzbtB@@ZF8TFj9c@RBECxFhiXP9vd9@/10au7Pk3fgrFJoM7tNs2CSQxMRMDJvE5BHKBJCdLGE9jt6Enxva4zQ9Pkvnce//YF9j9fx9hX@W@w/1rn@JsfaukbrVtDJk5u2c/m88M7m5JpVKpVCpJpaoe/FPTwBzQsjuKN5AN4Dt4HhZwU3zPZnFVSZyB0/DKVZ9Xbu@i7WY76PrjoJ3XOV0LrmnxAS3YWF7dr@EQdCz0@rLWy9Pc5cSpNI2D6JKpcgvL@O6V49zOVpIljLmHd8oZw8bt9EP6lGjGFl9VdqtpHbC0lMN27FWI7c/BeDCWEAhdCZ@n5ajMP9KT8K5xN0GIDjJ7lt2kWmee@DzIx026x4wQ5/XSTYaHcgMRTqum@/D7SHR3S6lzrUJV08uZdPCf2T0ezutxiysMT8ph1P1Y8i6muzfPWawmwBIRtvV9U8gUZJjHtFp5G6J8mdtj/d6UTMA33qfr3TKrNGcI1LgkS7pRyMtt1i@cDFbGDfrFhtN7@gXAs2DUFIYybcOelo5Iqzjlwh9YWov@Qko6QbGoKCTXaFi5MuaZsn/5FtfZurXO1lSdrVSd8QhIV2llyrRSVepeQPfM64Ju0BndIp2RhLUz/cwT2/Sv1/eH2K34shQuVUJXLV0tVUggLwVLlXqehPJSe6myzQ/RUuWQHz4vVf5KD8nYWvq6VDHDAhmG9MoPL/Fdi3C8t5YqW3nnW2bkfw4iU6@3VIn7lPL8KK9MESIF2k1aI47Yen3dzNEwoImNlUpXgWMiF8sn3odx@f8S/SfhvDjQDxKxx/mIM6tlVU5NGtaMIfXQtGECScwYyRU9m9f3d9i8LM6CapZpjWeXYfCkhueW0sJIEEMqn2jQLyEIuVmZjZGyZrJ7oqNrJw7lTk7Xz9TzWB9o5zn9mDKfJJVwDDdd3vRXGoR04P3wROHb8JxCx1THGOFM1pmBFoj689KcRqGv07jo3rd7iPe605kI24LJIr3EYC2ZTjocH86hskF/kGYSTsWlhtAuw5tyMijBvRPFWCrokXlLMn/WLYNgsAe/M685VjmglhJBSDwuncgoi@cFlsVISmSdpanK4CMULJlDIzxofeb4eNv6kfOJuHF5rrhtGjJlpUqWXGkxSYU9eAu79EdSe7x4rcOH2PctX03JG@y15AHAKhnXIvK1/x36e1/0d6NQGyJMVDBLsZ49lU6r13Nn2QnMu0m10x2IRFdtOzOVo7iGhOS0OrA083m8NqXiw@RDlHypNIY@oe0bssVrgjvoNrm2EFjQEoZX6Y@fV@jj55XbCTWtkXSvPKO0eKhJw5GGx5gmTZuPqzR8Vhcjhfe3/e53d/Aw3cF25wEeN2A4QXIZ5cPLHlu5JGObxLZ8gUgtV5QIcj4ujbs5@Ujino9u42Nb@rDfPNje39v9SJPu06dPHT1HjxP8MGqx1xrP4wKZbdXj@WDGsmXFRRArHHZjOz467w9HDz71slOyRIQ1KQM@1WLYT49xR8syS55PjF0qJ3ktimpYn5Nh4KekElQdH1N2qOk6IoIEo/wjXwMx6i3R2@XVmsPhmprNnn8RNJs8fZlo2noWQ9eYE3Hn77kHxctoyFGjJdbYdSbDbjvU9r768Lp2pI5e19XOu62/qo/779SH2t4RPDa8fbe529hS9H9977CuMrZVqUJcRiwoia7bQStAsF21Uio9UQx5qz8Yi9zJbzny/dC/UK/7rQDHVC8i/@Llubx4vWC0IaXqtBwdYw8z5DicF@EI9hYcOJKWsVBu2nwRE5crFOU9pTXtBda8F/122AkpbwZr30EYRObunuqG1IMkb831dVeUJMSIZNMhjv0KC6xrKu5TfpzdEBhf7K9AYuSQoJJtT2nCxf@@m4JH9YM3hwrOP7b297YbR439vUO1s39Ar28/NvZeET0bh0cHjc13SOKMb/a3GzuNrRp/EARKnoJXjl8uo9FcFDxkZ6q0PuPk2xtQ98dv6V1vaPDq2ucrqZFauuxB@oR@N/wtaC@tZy4jqC@4BstHBSq/WDt49Z7mfBX8ihNOcxTM9gfZdxHHLV0sqRdcGw2WDRpv63q40rRXKDt8HnExVghdFKyzt448P7vKAGcjnnYYqOwWbFSw9y1OPXgsG9BU0QOCDVDGYKWqOOTY0pL7gkFuUG2tbh8eWKU2MSLULyj60piarGeYYtpWBkBxfaTRw35QeT3@QHxPH1Z0taOhZFCP4w@SQT2RD1BFG7AdUas6x@Vo/xLiWa3Jh18uBjt8LKyexh82fV7FPtM4Sb9xl/oqDtkIFyddDiwnuzwc/NaPWmHIRSLOj6Br3a4MjEDCfZJMlKNEtm2jnFkSNh0cNWizN4mijVTiBtgJ@Z1RpPJVx1NHMA4KeqGE9Dvr@j0xgUpMd5j31DN4k6rqG@9hHAqPL@QM@syACMOZxiMut621wuC@5ajk5lSNvraR5HC0xgTtLgQ2pxD4I2AIUCG10mnxTMW3hAGm39GsnI/6xJHYt/3dzk/s3L5sBakC2mor/0v422@OJrKbWicZO0XGjrrot2BIaiUfZXb6QxrjLFY5eBikYOu8PxiF0of5dAv4xImnOcqNiY1q@7m6kaoNdJissdfvWZWeEhffUuspMeV9amWOl7PzWHwlUaWJ82kSFrs7oOOf9q8C6@zMxSHSdYDtF1KE@awcm5/jEWMi@mcmkR2/KwSjfVbd2N78VPj9ZxcRaUUsSEBoY3SI/4kxURcNDz7nY4PFIfQuPdJMJMHo8hSltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPQ1rXvWyux2libjz9HZeVJr/zx69fq1KqAMmko4hH5/lEurnq2FTpcpkTpU1ALNlJyJKsz5svLsOM5fVLXFBCL8A9Ug9yBOv2iTh9WoSY1p1edkiy6HDJurtj@I7aYIuKJNY8Lh7Z/VH8Kb9ZXd5wiolBibLImTci2jWQy45jmaXwfDUFbns@OJLf9wf3bC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7fC8u2wZFqyYN0f7O9zwMrk9ofAUtvd2wHLJDkNLeb0mDndxVxsTTu/xp@n@o7HHoHB3IsdlBioVdtlj4@ojT/zvBRwbDCJQnR4tF0/OFBZWZ9QWZJ7WDK0tRgE7AfqbWJtG/ZY2Hmx0hQvlmPlyXxJWbSZf/MG80zi3SIqtA7ianrEwiLxmt4Jb0Tq6ZmFVQi2vmeBaCiXxu6LkUHRsQb8jdaAhGzSaVYDMzObmZPJJ4xsI3BNN1d0Y9uGny2sZe5GEOLh2AZk2wT5Z7hZMrv/Poh@XDH1iIIFn1JocJs0aZpvaJ1wSBUPKKPnpXtwTreYLoWRvSjYOUM7GH6V0hr2n2coZiRRwkUXtsS6Vo41aqIfLxo1hw0SMQ34sPTUiWLRTAlGxPOXF3aHOsmkl09PQaRkIiztS5srqPjJNz2FMTXiebIaK@T2WFtkbI4NlifYndWw12/P9BC20GuT4mGyKpK2c6sq/GOqklkiVZOh@czGmESCvLa6@vgu2JOtMMULfxa2zCGT8nN0MaD1fQIyGke8vU@c29hzTXrCAHNIJ6b1ZsBMFCRVZ8ackmo7T0Y2foSL7AsRMggCgEi/k7U66mYCt9nQZUayoXOWqTZYQzhuqIyaKep/m18dBPKd9T34/vpksCETTAe/wSr/TX8YBcmtPMtjjvUJngbS34LhsMfZ5D7TBaDk@RrT3Mt2fNtODF6lVUjk8za7JR19O0nMbl2z18CV8Paih@De2N1bn9zeK5TX7abuNHbr6hE7Be2k9iKzw6xjyZ4HYW8eAiyDeV8C0wff4XsYVeh/wsE1IIlMfJsvz7Rx7sSNKUJa8zFHidJmoVq2lid7vxO1/B58rLjZh5HKuj9QQd6Fre/vOLN21kvrqfKEXDTo5amUmy14WS5K37ChC0hpENKb@G5NWLipYSwlcb3mrA/7KBxsBTeye8aWk36x/Ky09jzDreu5I/fi@PmJ@6hVzSqafP3eRXQ5vG5/PuufX3VUVw1@Ob1pjX/7VanVJ@ox1bXyg3hmLq9Vi@wM9yn9faael5hzNYI/8hV5BJv2JAqvUksqWYevP1AOP/CiuYIbEhNcqh5dGC7EFbtR9eJ47aTaq5bWL457J@u45Ddaro6Wy8t5fPiBZlGSMXIyfzw6wZxq77oGvSsF/6cc7VVfDVF8NYS@vPGHYX@3tvcqtRsHBQBbYNrWmzfUJbD3AqzZcPfE6wXXeb1N5ipwbAYKUmaBbwWV4QqA95OxHdMOCTPqFZe02eiG/46dzELJuxyM@pxivF2CtdTX8GtmwVxjKvGOAmU5Do1PTNwvIDhJnjwOhuTrWKyoC2VR18q4O@lYII5RksVh9lM2izuFQFTf5To@yURe4LfOgQQi2X/lYurFC45rT6wWebyLB1MOf8gXJkoneMQBCP0M@LQBVbDmHvG1jww1H@9lPMgX3qMa8T0ZNpDPsKaIFJh/qy98v4nLvyACCOEXROfy9Ban1rxIkZS7g7y5AFdy6YU/jhlwrVI6ZQGNBWypr5oAZ0txphGq1WSi7wvXIKfQiv7pFhTK/DbVjDi/I9mZJHxOrd8i0JK7lJM28NNNiuWtYgVTzGS2SLFwJzWw00XLozcBDaux2gq6XUJaaLGQkAOPfL9X178c1x8do86TGHlJL0ylF1LpnqQLUkkujyb4JFPFzpTNfUnyfVPZJJs7VVdVsfLiUU@3PFJJkrzr8/JG3qjfDJPMG3FXClfGCS9SCQUr5acZvS8pD1JlYgaP048lXfP3iu75GMtU3pfp@vGb0R0UsPGstjWZ4FKvF3Z/zOgg6DoFbJYlaiolxTm4pTKDqqrvYGpxQhoc9vl52G5UEyjLZSNxeMxkN168zHpayfgxP4mG3GKcGlgzxohFJa5zmQl3wxcWqR5OfmCBYJhgNGVG7oYpPNaFxxZY5HpgqpVbkFMDnJo2OcSruBf5FX/MYE8jZ/LlZicuCOY30ni53ZwmEAvdB9nZZEpLE1wXkY@6UXNmkaTu8STE2UJiz9oFjusM5A52B9vgD2I5YQsKIymm6B6naEonGcqGfW/rQiR@y/y9@Cjzyicde9ANblQNywyfb2FlUhfcR0E0iuBlix0ARZeDQRenjqzwXfMVah1sYGUVxy0JRGtm9zINWPZIfhdP@kI6FfLUPiBfw0AkSYguz85wmQw3YPvXEK3YcQlHXqbWG8uGBo2ZxytyzTxQcL7BArgbntlISM/J6AGlo4HfCrwM6WgRaT8ZaWon1CFheT8d90bgzI2mtEom8y@XYevz1iuc5z4tlx6XLZJd6ePgkvf4SXLBiohkElbgj3G1/CSTsc6GW3I2XABAV@1ion9PvBlcBb1ekKnRjMEZI1Jao2B4FbS9TOYgiA@BAResjJNJ3MPuXw5bsrlDSpdPzIhbwpErx2HEYfjF/CzHxS0@K3MzOLRKTpupq6/CNghobpx0@jgd5gMLuAkQeqDQRTAiojxyVBolPnvWuLDucoGNKKIG/JxYZxMxGXr9UdiinuGdrEyXQMkxSFJZrz2BCdXX6vq4HOzNQgDXYxIKGATMUdI8HDL60Py7cFC6YeaM3Tc9UyTp1@exQsM9GIYkfRMCc69wMQt36uCj141Ddbi/c/ShdlBX9Pz2YP99Y7u@rTY/8hk3DsrZz7F6vb9L0iU@TZdT8336kK0dUsksJ2Rqex9V/W9vD@qHh2r/QDXevN1tEDQCf1DbO2rUD13V2NvafbfNp@8EQe3tH6ndxpvGEWU72ne5VlMsk5RT@zvqTf1g6zW91jYbu42jj1zjTuNoD5XhVL@m3tYOjhpb73ZrB@rtu4O3@4d1hYZlthuHW7u1xpv6tkf1U52q/r6@d6QOX9d2dycauv9hr36g2EjAauVmnbCsbdISFjVxO7cbB/WtIzQoedoi4hGCu646fFvfauCh/rc6Nad28NHVQA/r//KOMlGi2q69qb2ixmXyd1CF@mXr3UEdHpRAicN3m4dHjaN3R3X1an9/m2l9WD9439iqH66rzO7@IRPs3WHdVQhYyVUTDKIWpdPz5rvDBtOtsXdEc8a7t7B3cKiTPxBhCMsaFd1mAsMMAq0lIu0ffARU0IE7wFUfXtfp@wFoytSqgQqwqNg6srNRhUTEI7uZaq/@arfxqr63VUfyPsB8aBzWHeqwxiEyNGCQ8ZFYhyp9x61GPxFe8kjMmjGc63J3qsaOqm2/bwBznZs44LChuYXJtvVa09yD52NrEyXsY8/Av7A3VjrTn64C@Pqc3pGZvUcTe0za2t@u04ysnV1lk4R3NOs8m3ClZKfRTBMn0mvKZU07OL08a4a9Th93TONisvFxEZ25CMPkIIbNp8ycaGR6f4UL5HLN5vtakxa6h82m496nZAqNu0robfB5uRzdRsS4wMobGz@VitD9RYpQGz/og0421MMBBHIK9X8Q0zf/InBUsdgOdDFc3gdgs3UUybHJOY5SSDTyZUcE30mq5J0Jfg81O3DBvAHvtZrYJ4VlJGfqR/Sn9zV5kcnB@kDSWba7ikUsYhmN8LfAVCOVsEsE/qM9EoQdrtKLguDzWb5kV4c1v3fW77fzjmPKcN4RrQPP8s4dxU@Ds4nihcnyjCwfO@vwEJFZd7MKE58/a5Ip3S/ekFuWx5/miH8cg434fMCuKVfFm9V60zL/gxSHRZKrtGsLXK/gTobO96b2t8YHrOZKK0/WJ76/jr/L2IK9ILwC04R3zOVO@Of1iWSgAca@OIgkofaQUSxaZYy9SZz5mjKeI9N12IblD83V5wHP60QSUmQv/a5dJ2bjYXhjY09y@NVB7c3mu50dEp3A9smz1adr65nY7dbfXPn9iHrYcS97HRvQPE56GidZo2SLFB8eKZbf9IT9mYGLRWSEf3zTafwRfh5iu420JRMEGZobIRJVDyZ62QB0yCp2wPEgY/h15sjUDJBPNdVBay78G1bxfdKVmAe0MUt3zL12gz@AHQ9/M8TjBmkG0izGroyJc2l1wXIvu2NMRXlxw457kMXLGj4WN24xDXiri@1ncbuW3zRvW70YiSkjxit3O5ckJB5MYqGMXUVPRvZb9jOiN4DZexh9@ZvmN3r8qB3csbs7PxrVRodExp24JPapk81o3ehjDfkE8UrgVM3U9EJhl9/RSPHY09vJsWMQazQwKgi@AxvfNOD12I/IZJVsAftyyVFfhFPhvANw1jXH6nfi3FnN0VDWjf8Q/W68UiiBFTs5Eapdx3VkTJaPsR8LQ84Umf4UPRj@P5EmM@C/oBUnQU@oZTkBvBclGarQipavTJTw2hw0WKcbCTXtTx8TMN/sjjmPG6ZPb27kfg2RQPfO2Hz4yG4PO/kZBACTY2PDHr@xSdq5T0unl1lHF8c5Sa91McgrPVeYqWIKbmHtxGW1yzVnK3hxlCN7TVaFu1RUvZSF2ymPeloyTSzl1cMoK@Ac4/@j@Ig3QOIBz1x6Llark5xV0qPMyAHtasmacNqxxyRSS7/demr3SFkuMlOyX598GUIR6A3gM91ODtzSV2Kem/a4yDOxOmIveHDPjmUyJh/tsu6UDTG7AeA8bPNmCGK7jK4xQXQFOrvqS6Cp/EM2FEElidVh4mcQ4tbxiLQ8rV7H2PPOJDg0xv5dTyIDBLKrZXJ44uBDY2hfl/fUG39MKHfv12xhseKjw74L20VUJtsSujzi2LT6/SGpjj7aTTi64djx1Ae96RD0osuh9l9I81k41DsSRumnaqA2yeqdpxlxyc@oReEItxXaHvMHN@kigIWouCe5KaypPDGv4dENs@kY3iyXVf5FkvKCaMJuSZmIL9Sa@vpVcglBtcvQgCkYRvHigm02uR6cO8TD77o//Iy5HypQrx20Y8@kFkjeC5ROavTYx2NrJE0f9CPe0aCuwA5ITImybKTFhqo0Rz/V7KTtmrKJd0z4LuWWfH89MZMaaymqKGFcXTsx31qBOhNUWtGuQWNnoeWVVUZl1oLr262LMfYWmj62VtlPvVikVESJqD40qiOeRG7GTx/xpDf5qw8jjB76gjNurYICYeisOFedlnOMH2wKPoTBsG3viZIm0/YH2H7jpU@/x7xotg6127@WP4qCMa0AWsXwpsgwmvm/9M97za1@1z8L@6FP6zT4078RiYfHMT@iw86G/euIQzRxQtvK1B4nz@JfRtyw4T0@l1y3XHNFo2CQt80URsNx7VzcRPDOOYwAk/CwzN@DSR9pcZknq0mhTPr@KdvjlZ31W8s@Ls8qLCf6AKAF3MaEBYXcIR3xxSTr8un6VIbTeRksHE9VQfnOLRZ7KYyfE4n4GCaFsUFmyizBbgRWZrdifNy@cdvsg3AIR0vBdoAAQ1GeP7s@Im6TFPkRlgIVVX5WsorKKcoN/BDiYXw7uVee/pOxJwT@BPrlx7O4ZRYjsIjrGG9LkaxXtJdRwoXNA0OW0SyJSYqFZ2HPun7I0TxuJqGmk8e3UYMtf0gp0m72prgSIzJPCx9EEsw3SeQ0xw4mlSW15LDfDqggtVG@dDvDBnfZz/LgxyGu7JxBMG1pyHkL6dtI1SIqIabxhHmtjbL4VL57xKys3LfXJghYnWVyZsXWzmeN5sI3UEKZX3Gs1R@SMM5OUE@beixFo/5g6Z7Uu1V2zPTMNovWLce50xBYmK1Kk@WjNpO2OsbjeD0zic8E06QpxpZmxENYvvJzzOaTRLypNjHeqs3xHXS4jWaJ3VQ8qcT93Zaxj0nxCha9ZqKJhxTjDiel6/H34yY1vHm7BNEwZXnVZInRhMhojuXRAjVBpphK96cQc5/GfYIebaIc6m0T7ez@uZWok0ZyxuWpSUo5uQQ94bgdlzZJLg06ML6AmzjRcGMhFSucN@6Yj/LKhVM4GUaCAIRWHBSSfSjZwU06a4KPODpAJ9@EtVAZkoieNmwLh9jpf0ww9sqvN3e0xUNzXCifrAukmxgSrSo41zxI5r45vR43bxjKFCloiM8gRdyiKdl0fv9W/dm2UD6CIKU5WVv6llw0xlHLhA39sZOaN9CBk6p0ydSISg@EJosGGgu0SjnrBrJchfYXDoXjYd2ghxEtIORzHj/LugTcea@VYmqjyE17jCyOJreMNkcVNqRIwlDyDvLroSiqLi9cCUAgGFP5apkgwK0pY49DAXa9Y3NeClHdR1SwWsawpI/sFTWx85yRDqLqDE9WrRylWTme2zAKM4GQYjE7T4II6SyzsyRQaKKbiYuV4@ns9iQ5SCE2vC8Up67QvZKmYdxzQkAO5l1yEolyXFZuSXMwJz5ZdVKJMX9z6vOSlVqaTCX6xBgeF8qTqc9KqdRUtSsr6aKpkkQPx641lUikcGyEY6nw5/7x1RTb5XlsE2otMlJahrbPRrB1WmXSus37JVIv@FK20TEMPPtmuFl@NSXESsop@3wH7GqJjwzgu/1Pt9ZYphpMdKwA9ktnLrvkZUHIGmsWUz2ahZWu8bQXOygwa9p@R70/2tlJuX09HRtDo4tguFoqlcDEp7bze2Nbja2ksF9M5y52Lrvd4uD6L8P3p0WW/UHAIQEqZgUdUJfQoIi8/vBMIkMAB8qK3AV9kRVr/ctOxw7BgBNKdB51m@TU3hAUT0BhbPTy/og3gBiknmB/RgPRvp9VPPqufVE0NRRzDEWlYRJ8lTWnZ0QefOjAPjs@qWJgEMzGmonmLae68QUzCCKbcGex@2LnS2KenH0ddLt9V31AkGd4Clj4NllgZ8cuUJIsOGHk272XEfujdVVwFXate8XIYvM6wJmJycSZMH7h4Rv/IDir3wzy2eOfsjStUJOX0cxl@Kd2VfYs62hn8fcAK3xIaN8r94U/yLeYTpOZaarXIzh5Iowel92Za59UFof3xDTN7s4Nos5G12NnDdR0h3UB48ueu5dbckv2mLjZTzflDmhYEhgaJ/hcuV8JXDX754nFq1Gncz@pyGEApGO/SyJKJJQ/JxD5DIBHoB5@RE940f5rgYb1zoRDEVFwEKxjWu6gQBMFMpmHreqv1/laraYWB8vLqlbbpIdCQdU2a2obHzY31Ta9b@L9h@rK6uq6yNxt5wt93DQfv6lNgsE7nMut8@E2vVJaFffGYK2NLl4sVhfd9cVm9cXGelQ8rm3iWj89/ee//df//Pf/Vqzpl/@Bl01@Of4pzuR5XnGx9WXxh2/reD/ePllaPD1eHJwsna2Dy/7OXsP7jVHBT8xHveFpJiezgPWV7UjNOpu9z@iiygQPvPCHn0m6VFSuFRVz@mskkaNYxuZagfU9wD3KU1rCm6ADk0t5QiJHQMfYjqfeaQUwwKP5hihJuMAOVMrL2YrZuIc7mDhDfKqS0554WGe9CnCnJfGkgLu4NGMVwl4U9LADfsU6rzQvk/HpNxw1Nf8Wf3oTnW32b9SjT3n1qKQeuepRNss/5bXn9NVZLIa4nSvZaDmQzbqUkhwtwMxQRSErerx@4Fg7E@TOZBY5ZA8gGTcVnFluwbnx6o8vy0jAtegss4CYpkq2SPiQCUVyXxZ736hbvlCOb9nUVRtWFJp6FcOVWScqcf9CBfIjMQRIar4QglT6VCVO@vhGMp6K5ovu6wxHE2LAIOvBqx0e9/hAc9FiT9s8p9ZSCHPE5vPyFXPjulyGZrSRIvUnCPCBiiwnS3yTcCm3lBErb6uV3Ey5hW23TzOf2DqMg5GxTZdCvyuLCcSa2ybcYk/fa9GG3HK8orJhfLxiVZWdtP1WGavIxWV3FA70dQWuHQPqS1zbNxlJ6FEGJHDEZ39leoTxRoHxFDXRLRIsa6zafTRdRkJPX02nDnY8OTmyiFD8KU9j@@vE2HaKfEvEsIPwACMVm/J1/LAbaa8rQyb2mT88RXRAv8MB1UZybsb7eYhNO4FxvxMj7TFkNjlPxjM1JTcY@mcXvqtye/2joT9u0LRFms@o5TnUQrhgAhIYfLrqWc0zCEuLdJcwReKmsOUQghd0xzo8mvRtNr5zgi41Q0G7XcEgSLETUzL4muqrCTomXP0dnWCjPCW849NILWJZ8sLSSEPK2tdmeJhNDZ2MqcEeO/HAyWYE1XhkGl7QhS4x0V7wwS9J8i58BOi6s/oWoL6KsPYc9WN2Ogt6fmpyGnQz5qJ/cV3JvIjxzKEoxRopo6E8LScR74AV6ZE/pb1AyNxk3BllFvL5hU@RDueWs@cRdvId2@IXfRXGAeg4gBnfDFHveqEIy4kZKomB4akGW/4ThE7XPyP8xtf@GKz4KZf/8UHROf7pU@/kUf5T7@un3xzGRItkM8sWVE4fZhuJpccKzYxFN/VqrNIi42rwUy@d4VNPyR0WiwSESDF//FPx5GuREPqUc5xHxU85IUiqy4BJcX59RYAvTqGZS2NRzGUWnEeO6fz8j2VH0dzKv@hD@eDIL2FhFpW8TU/rnGGHQPE93V8v5cpJVHy2UnqyUn5CK6Gz4KYwDC4x3xaiy9PghlSJCMtZmno@/ZbihhQhvt1E/jp9vKF2SlgTuXsS6UtKWoTqYc71ZGK2ojKe8ATlJyqzu1RccXHiPD4OH7HgdxWxnMnLvqDEdNDivjzmz6h/gXr8CHJt8naIcCSsDMRGhLdQC4Bsgq/cxqGOGS5LfM/JU1vw3cpAqHuLOWu26PV7Ba2sOd7SOpRo3JrpPis9K02O0akhmhqhi1qZWnqgyhs/Pv2P/77/a26U21gpfhjS7yj3a27tWU4e6YHeHpu3q9xG7gWyrX3LjYu0BqbHp//xP6n8xl8IDlLGL@jPxqqBtTbObRSqXORrbmONHsorK1Tv//rXf6U2LMqKDbFYF5uuYsTWDUW2/B7zLqWrBlopy9KlRKzwxSzAEAtDWpvTCwyjblaelXibLqetKq4C7fnK2KPoKZ4Ns0ZsKiQ7GcaegjQjKVBFBQUBaUwoOsqy3TBmG2DeBE3180NvLaIVwM/anCOuMjbdeBjBZGhRlkXUgXmpkdbz8rBR@jEbm3dUssamZN2okFjaaVn77PE6scPbfjAKW2krCTNcL1r@dXDqgQ@9oH1Ja6pe1O3/MixeEUtelFeeFTvY3C@yHXdxwJAKg7H3GymCOhgQLQzZ6NRVQ@qB/gVceLkcLYgU@p34TMrEkyQtexC0ZA8rHZOYssgdP1eOh9EcL1Gl8/yXFHhEztSBIK1YaZ96VHL/oKKyy3FGycdrXgfYvGXjWO0CoyDWsAOWTV6G24DdQdMerzY840tIXApe1yWL57fbTV@n5TMLWRMqzc0snAfdQTXbEffu8J2KExNNf1Ezb4VSCLGDUCiwoAOsi2Dk0xK9muUvWI8nNcBNij5rjV3FJWTt6Lx6Vd@uctSVOVVfS9XX1KPQEpJ6Yp6xvLEpO5vIliq2KodBE0dqMyum2iITtHno8Q8wiKRbGh1cS9DN4RuQRLWkOdqqzO42l9fCxCPXgdzZk61FiVydySWXH12TQ25QQ3dCvZ5URgICXnArsFCm90O5AVE1YUbDXkb8@U0kG/8eGgy3YR@uRG23deJ8VKal3hVi34QjvkupiATar6xtg52R2SMGHbvYikPQZrHxknXAUp0KL7Y4o@mOCoeBNi6hslnZpzpuqTi8bEdHr5VAEfQhWyqvPH6yuvb02XNEOVvQrZ0NBoU8rAIG5z7BYI06T4tsfK9Ws0tZ@YQQ1NNVAvossDiAg1nXteMYt8/XzoNquaSBlbIM65rDaEhxvV3JIBOIw8DDjEBrlPwwm8//WDlGw04@tZ2v9D/xt/EPyAxn3NH6QnqrH94mnqkyF@JwoMqCmZ3i5B/Dg4qjU@y8Qb9zAG8TAWxdhe2pol14gBidD/uXZ@c2d3jatdURDRgiOPulxgrqVTBKHIxZWEEX1RsODev2RdXAO55uAYxyMSVA5xPgNMy030pfW5pidCzRJATPmrixiiNEy3TUZmfmzl5f1fe2JxHL2WHoGK5nW7aScseezOBABrF6reYeEXW1twu@SqplkpvyqswCroR8Zb4O7@OudAuBqC2qGFnNesMoP48sZebFxLVpUpT6EXjNgFku3U1Kc6/VtAIEMYJQ7ybFQsyNz3NskiU42Z2McQpezlYsG9E3YRSxgzldWdbRFqWciaMKLGRuAYh9m1JWGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIccr1WBmTg4zwVa3kTjARtRxQwu0v7G35artOv3Z@bDtQlHerP0V7Y5DPN@Ob1njW66oxo7pAttbLNvcwmbqV1xRImYpaYexCYIQvh2JihgkXgPqjR1NexnUx6mxfZJwBdjV10q42R3VgwSOXngPZEEv3mNXHHxdh79VZPNqWtLELlX0sJAtrvkD26LJQlJrDElIeQ8QK5MgYkctCbcvJAwvFuiseft67WIYu7Ezm6dTLCsLKlLbd4pE9jTP3kqZeWyxotlipYJ@nMcXzLdzeeM06PT1XbSYOe7gjQd/jDcK92eOwv8XzFH/53DHY80djyuQPcIdsdtwvtHJYdj7MzjmdMxzcLMdnoXYH@pYr2hEybUAsMADhrhDSonlEtp2izhR@dkJy5PzEYyEVlZxMeAPNf6JbvyTCmQuP24H/682vvAPbvyqbvxqBXPNjJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JEJcynP8zsXqi7ks35oy1d0y1dq2A2ndHN/9dbWvg/1NKnuqVPK/CYIAcO4r5@PjeLJlI73Go0EnMLL6OdduURx342VzpYe7WrWVo8dLqX0XkV2rr6w/g/0/g/gzTiJ4Shw1lEbBsar@VleSqX5UWz5F0OhUtW0hJpr/GMbrVXT1jJekRPUCKkeWNrqBcqpJC7kpicNnmJ/phI33jyuS/OItt1sEwcnFsLaFkRlp1kiIvmq4NkrqzF88o2@0BWW0cHu8v/Rchw4X/Wt9AIeXTtddDtmpnEXoIdxV6ndGOs5gD2oV5zpFhFk5ORHenb3jG7LNwu1dixxcS8OHuRIEdtOP@jtdQF9A0rKje2jIg2ni5vVlUwzTXLC/lCbZdMs5usW/yHuPS55tLnFXWgFwa3kcrXG36aF5N12srq6rw5QEp5@MEALLmUf86o@t8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ftoun)

This answer is for TieSoul's Python Befunge-98 interpreter [with IP wrapping fixed](https://github.com/stasoid/Multilang).

371 Fungi/378 Multilang/367 JSFunge-98/284 PyFunge code is now this:

```
@,,,"371'_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@
           ^ IP
```

First `k` with repeat count `-1` is used to skip over a single `;` in Multilang or `;#` in Fungi. Then `k` with zero repeat count
is used to skip over a single `;` in JSFunge-98, but not in PyFunge (`z`  `9` for YABALL).
`'` is for fish, `_` is for DOBELA.

Answer (score 1):

## 379. [Noulith](https://github.com/betaveros/noulith), 16418 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?MLot ~7+<p>3:s5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce:ss~##       @,,,"371'_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)( )
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdlWpuqS69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIkslSq6e3Z73bZn1tPTnmi3Pb7tnvVsez0R453YWbd37JkIez9OOOaTf0D5sbHh2HD/g95zTgIgKJFSVXscMbGxkAgk8nHy5MnMk@fk46Cje8Of/SyGF3viWPOB5UzYxPAmrOeaZ4Yrs7tztqubXl7LCgLG2nMH05FhT7yKEGMqY5ZuD6b6wGB905oYbpp5hsE6huWcQ7jG2PbUnnpGrw5vWcZs45wd2l2zBxDYxDk1bPO14UJYjrF7hvVm9GbCus5opNs9j41d055QaJ6xJzq89KfdU6Z3vImrdyemY0NQgbFntqWPOj2dUfSxa/BERQaguqeUZjmkxNgjx/UMyMHpGp7noGcZPHXXdB7uPf74Snw1wz7WAamxZcyuZK@q7DPTcHtXU2js05P796/6ZtnXJMdm96@jpObY3nTiHE6uws@zvYFh60yTy7J2NbAAxJwYVilTylwNKkJ9GhOzu5QPBNw3Xahd3a9F1tVtqC2syy1mjMaTOZN4/euWFdatx3SPTb2pblE8ezrqGG4Q0Zvo7sS0B@zcnAzZZGh6YTqK7Y31riH1DMscmROjxywTEjl9HwqAtnvs1JifOy5UuQ/Tsa05JDS6Zt/EJAEeABCvxGRocDgjfQ6VbE@gcTCdeYCGZQTQkkIM4t8zOtMBc6aT8XTCALee6ekdC4B25qxn9PWpNUmzDoQBkcn/fGjYfmMGcDKAOHE4Vi@nhJqxaPN6r8cy0I4Bj1ODmUA1QqvCslnwZ44LVINYAUY@MGrXvIzGDOoMqqjvVFg@k4Hwg9AHsdUtz/GRWUYNA23oq1RnCPeJ6wxcfQTU6BlE008PnzCv67jwBj@My/vTTWC6@oRtb7P4weN7cVYPq0V2O0JYRTV2AVUQCwLZmW5NoYVEa8KB@nHD1AJWWXwjXmFxIIuWYbkcy0G3LTEtD0RSM2VwQP/Xsir8CkwrsZwKPSgfT2M@fVcfmJbBoQwQShEbvpZnGtwzOZZVSzzmwLH6PFqXMiuybIkViqyYZ0W4l1lZg9wQdI6p5Tz8CvADaGVARYVfNscBLdo9tFNsa/usr49Ma@5DJ/BdlldZESACvipA1koAAZ7ZLP6y8CO0lq8o7MkQqD3UzwC8ZJmnyI2MkCFhFSrwULa2FOKIyHJ59t4QswfSAdHyJVaE7AtAiRygAJTVSpB9PsML4g0Ny/KTDT1MRtgWM/ADzItAhxJQPwO0zCAxi/CDd@B3GjA2DbiYBoxJA2aiaeDOYhYQrwBhBajKgk@voe6dQkY8H61HxAeODmBUpDYyMRWJBBCgtlgW6qzActAQstgQ8lkG@AMuxQIDPlZSWSnHSkUG9CxnGNSNCnhhK1GBf6qAj4rAoP5VaAAq4KQCtVUAqmbzTIgQW81iOKTNQlogjZqDNDlwQ8WpBfxBOmgZKmSpQp6aVl40QsBNy0N581lqnVoBarcIYUA3DXDVoDlpgK1WgnBMWwIalrDxFuNpTggd6QC1gs0d2iEQIw/4EFyIC26tmOX0063xUO8gt@YpO31MWsBuUEAyQtIMFg@eOaQmoJIBMNgLAH0NWkAWyJGFqs3mwuwtFYA0ELzRM4lBWybwLjWkUDFNDfKlPp4syKYWCKPxfDIM/TTu5wDjNIH5GQO9Ow8Dofelw8CFbyGLvhrx2gWgTA59PeCsztSzFkBCR06jrIwz01r4lcivZ@i9vukN3y5wzVEmHUOf2ObpIpd8Ph0hqh4JKGDAklcxG407MSUYrgZDdC3KohUxztgJK2gJZVUl9DpGf2oPDKlciuBHIZOpO4GBZZFnmXu75mAAY/ICjpqmYtJAufDOE4ZWNjsRQk@kLubpmjB832HdIQgUYWCZwy@XFzCyGsKY6x0c1SWQwmAUKOO41TdnrHOnS6PGAsEs0ak7NMdB5MrayJHKpUxmpUKkbRDlXpcyIWvGqyW/dEw7EWfxpHApwFjDJcvoSA0D2mc4SuG4i00XxlWHpIYF@0zYwciYBKItD/Iw6lrARqFSujqOwDgeGTSeBnDMicwgExADDecMxVYaFJey8Wjg7LgopYKU0zNcl2FcEG29NA2x3rTjGa@mKEct8OrDmG3A0N7XTStEgMYRfUICADzjHuQ3X0a77zojGmxGOIRajjNeI67AgH2OgB4458YC9cV4ro/HFkhN4G9woQ2QOddJ3ibhPJorRwgSYTqocABIWYG0YbpGl2jvFx1SZ0EuWUaxwrT6nSxCuRsRp7LQWUDU8DCNPbWsCsg5Rpdl60rPOFPQh4tcy6IW4hAIYSBK@SA6OsjKiDlhEUK6o8kk3p0ENes5o@Wi8fH1MCz60ETByDrX51B7fRhajZk@AomeodgMPZeNoMXwGsSaAJ0Fi3XIeo4dn4RQzl0QYqHQYUlIUEaaTMyRAdqPA0mwxnOENI7uhFlnDk2ZqJWTSd3hmFwhlCxcJRT3yEU8eGcBca837SLVMG/TphYEYpKHMr4LrJL7CROXNZs6/FyQ58a@hiejAyMeI2oRBcHjvd2XvLsEEWVUw/ZArfBkZqL@BS1/4PShsZ2bUHZgWJB0AbtLREAShF4zuSsLRHJsQKNTi5msOx4z8IdBCZrn/UwJRFDnpcleQ6A1BBWiO3XdOZuNoSbMEcSadJ1@H1rva2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1Qyth6h5xCD6Y6Xi7l42zQgjo1Kyf6TX2QDA8gOAmsftVNs8osCjMdUBCKFbnNh1taBUliE7nhOZBFiixR9x5HRv@cYHjUWxz0Nuz5m5hkD6hrQz/oLZjRC4RxaqU1KRQ84j9@9ED5mKKwsDGblt4KPDRu6ThdaJXR6qD6s0z3WByU7IsKinqF3u8Z44rcTh9iZaUfk/aP7KO@Tr@QDk72hsLnLtq@0GogatpyILIv6D6I@9tUQHXmtr8lLJHiEKifnLNb8WvYQ4@xK7uILjLOEwQtxDQ5j6hKo/BCTmE6QlSB3NLtD5IUT5DYkb0Nvc6fXiw9@0ezdEZP6Yd6IjQpsR5CV0AvxWA9Dgp91HZA8thBWfckDoy553AJa90YrIDshklYv6isrugxM8TagI8d2VkAFYoZwMcpyCNUFNcZj5Bq6FTZG6i7eUh0hw15MLuFABmPoeOy40DM405nTTAJVWaR1@Qp4IhwrkjK7uzy0wpARxwF/gqMgJBhbOrQF7GLYU0Gz0oFTABPjCjLwPIfnGEGYej3B8vE7J9bPGxOMpbZtoHKmu3MOBIoHwzNkNGem6wIbPMNBgo9BwWAiUzuFMUHv9ZCzIjmo31/NXMYWvT/tmLOrWngXPeWXnnCmu6yPCrgLQgd0okS878WTVfKnlJEgUXHGE4WS8rsIESmSDFWe6INOD4PEfWA0x3O7mxCXupiYZuJ00i@JSXBgQi6jsU9AVbiKHaoP2GhGp9Cv6a3KBjB8SxLcJfQjTDBAkTFAd0HOgE4IWma53Ovo7A1wD5dJs32uigQqiSrnwrwMuxfm5RMCcYmWV@ZZeG6XHFJkVMMSYHQqOQ0SSwR8T0pQQhE8FMUfW9GDpD0eRnIN95zaNA/HElwUSbKLUPiFASBByJggfJhdc9L2xZU7dwLBZaNWg8YG0hSwzV4yqtEGE5YycGqILJM04mciT5zjCfaNRBLKi5EvOTYgNkFLrdXZxWToQo@j90sBIgFZBRtbckBYv54fm6fT3tWKttETI4nY60BoMrsTsSrA4M97Q@0mqsaXqApabxypio0X0xPoa42XfLFCRT@aa3go/tZ8VCI1nEAM/La6kkQ8qe@3aND7867liwTcBZ2dc6MOoH/qT2SFjCjtywRBp73WUzkQ7A4cDnuyd/Kg5vdFHqh0TLuy5GE5Xd0i702MLgZpHx7efbr39BfbK2BYZqdy1UMxc6UCDrXTmTSwp0pO1iqbURgLwPfaN8PGhMtxRMEPZpIzi4hK8y4MLrOAnEdPv3aVJCAJITkoB3Dj74pIw@OA0CV0dG94ZRBmg1QKsgyTBHGZdMgCmKEDUcdwPcDnyfT1a6y8q0iNfX/EzJrqHEDgqRzaQToZA68IYEFQp89HREoLUqhp40LDwhWNGeDzMUrNV5EhUTrSZD4@un/wtEZg/Xk1iaIo3gRkKd3tydDmrSmo4KviAPsDV5el5AXiKE8TrisJ3O0uEXhRt2wNfACAuo7sMMkaBUXzhoD7/tWyka/UDVsAvROEq3JlVB7qfiiiETxwiOuiyrtqFKWAxWAVeq0cscLQ5WGrm88bxVw5Omx1F3n2okBpUQDGgUBudCHo1JPQR15Ikb5Y7aN//PAa4h4JkaAKSAFmnsVkysuzBNReJJPFPWUfNDTHMuTPiOOJTEwqSjxYF5C7HimfkfgHM3OSyCT5U01CXMh9b@9QuxdE9qesaSaDlAbUxXFkcvu4vtf1oI3YjuUMHLYFabh0GGQIYtPaYu4NHPtaDenoiUWN4RIh8F@cuNHHMNaYr0lxpFRRdZUvNuq2dw5cWi1kkUhEIQKlUHz5pX6mA7kW5T4@/OIABhE1n8mE7gxdQIJIGiIXuroRX/JgEmQk@/isLGC4XHittwcBUmS9DgvtM7ow4d4ieKUncUxZWRl/JUqfONco/tKZX2la4MObFjgiJDt8/OTh4eODR3ufNydaPr/0nsuUC0A4yK8DspA85HTD3rrFuyYWC8HFoG@42L2AC0xBQQlWi6aeC4xbxigyR2BNq@ELrYlPnKEd95JXC3OOodJLu8ub0CPsfDyqnxAU7Z6FyojLV6txPMf2M5xMxl5FUaCXD6cdGZRW5WXXsfSBQulgYLAsRUXV5fAI5zW8VSkAGW9u8BR8cgtEhznNIOrWyAHlhda8kTWwBAdPs1aWORiCLowL44ablMMWTKVReqAhgK6shGUjBkxvQFv/GdSTyJv2V1WtxNu1mtFyihhEW@r@EHejb4DqlIDRCkiRvPLKmnead9gcuDRCugokxuQtmuTwGI4FFgNBkmZNUc8PiEPcAudLkVcQjV5NcTYXuJSSz@SKaiGvgFoGahrIrBLOuUkjfdIdShNHAniS06d5g0gr7Htd3e7LW74jQBbkvo@gqNnG82bTboGA3rxDuOG6c2PeaqitZJVdT7Llx09WofUuFQ/bbuABbZec0DTpydbws55@nZ31dOpdPaZMRmN/zJHG7NEeCFKvHeDXPSPa9zCBEg1UtpbiKhj5rbJiQsjCpALekFIKdCgYaaHpKYiXBEIviofQcoBvRRKwxWwGLwff3xHhI6h0Y7s3nbhHayQo1@BsqTcGItJkcxe5tIfzgxMYHcOWj1waKheZNDs34jiPrnt8thIS@Wv8QXrQ1UIINCsfzkjb4a4GaASUitRz4BzQrnDadLiYZUSlH1oaZEg44eQDSBA2rR4MgM9AYl6QPV4QnhP5LBfp1HbObYTWMVhJ6pgTPtnvTF1c6zZ70bJB9KzG4wA0KlyEr9OieMfo8llWnphKAUqgzkbGyMGpBJCuiBUYVASdL6ijLujhjDV0q4yEK4YAX2K7@8DFugafL5JGqERBkzpg8Ymr7ElfKLr0GlrzDbIVFj5SxX6lnwQEWN7eQLMk/gwoSSfOiCJ9RvMtGHg3EHcFXDGEEkMLE/WaMzbsqzof1wgTySptQ4jH@SLQRXxjYyNeidfjaXDtgGsbXTvoSoFrh1wSuTCejC5KkSYXhjYoBfq14peNAPIs2cI2MEPJ4bU5TuiNSiXbSusN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6Ewmxfo5rtmA/B4p@z62neOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9mSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt50eylmpfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXL0qQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRfXMGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/cIYD@duNEI46wZSNs6gL/aq4JYe5OJRLvmap48KdEuafiD38ngg3OLkHcpL4znn7gLHtKks7YwKxt0zqT9yJrryqQxKkxwZLuMbcUWSYCSkEA6Jiv3I9LAL67bhTL3oTOPKCVDMHXxPhlNglsH2tDS0KnMsGN2hw@KbuwCdhes9OJTg0pXEF8ACAL2uDD9koiiV4GIJSBe0ocgEvkhbsWhWRiUkOOsJ5ubzhfErOcytSmlYBjMyB7bjGhKQBFIItHuK9uQJ9WBd@pBmvq6tS/ihNKSh4m0awBHvW45OtOXsOrIeNB5F0oN@DkmeGj3BAv7RB/Yo87pwjZ6yJdAqreMOYYSA0iAn1sLaGvkBiuONe/JkBkmFBA640UCu3YHQec56mqYVuvl@JQjDVgHEHkIloVZqg4obBEkqBCb9Sj7g00KBjv746N4BnzuhwRaHV5xHa4@c3hTkSl9vemrYgzQ7gPZk2s7IBDIE6V@fWk8dZ8K1fHhZNzPDlWZzNLV0mvO5Oi1zY7qu03Esmgq6Keki/tT1dEvnk1BB6N6nj0DWf3ZyXJMrkUiKfja6MW@ch1ydLafnYXTNkdZbg@UhjzdMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDoK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cov9aHSyMp1I8LjgusL1QNfI/m/T7S95Z8j6VkDVZC@8cefO9oEs6YhSlPI@EG0OX4kQBFShOuD90bbwixeO7W@RwZfFRuAlhaFjB0uJTkFhw@QwGfQvlKlBaUETnezgNkLDHuEpCrBvX3lgXhFDv2nwGdLaxxGMLsQ3qQDC4KSjSCJsK8@e@q9SFbMdfs/Q4W3VA56dple06X@VGncrl6pzCZ@U32wBiu14NNtyti4Y5xeNhNIJKuEEKKiYt7F8rarhNw6PJdoGSVAVPAXVipmWk5qx40HoTVzwiQ5@Jzebso4z2OegluFty844yMKq0x2kNvapBSNyXYTtzJoHEh7H4xHV3CHyGpWbLpIT6mdp9x@pJfJUMGgzj@hVWkL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2f1@BeqdL69QiR3aIhIOg@F@zNafrsDWvAkHcme2PLnLTYpTxx2kN/p5R9dV8pl0FdV597gr/Hpcb2nn78aSPT4hCEkY4rXyVei7NgezIIziAo4T5ycOFOnYk5IUmAdiKYWF5VBqRmtEgC6AMMnkGVhRn5JULU3xhvFmXpG6CpJgzE3JuP0sxIXsp9S59MDJu3Ob78uJ7cfJ3Iz6ZG2e/4iw4VlqGVGZBMTQwDFKvs@OTewdOnMrRcLxE/wBWcCnRHvTsEAWVdoQNKRgtfYR/14uwjTJNEtV2ArgbaR9tPD426Co0e9A/IHXnHwHAT4JnExZcueNN6FyXkEppPINxv1Z0QjUJgCSMJZSJglZX4P7O5quXjWYEWnyJKArkTdypAWzMpT23zlezBQENyK0SJc2UVxovaZoK42Kaa9DfUjXDpGDQsEhqhBI0Gk14Dl4PIImu1qnwPAMRFBcwdIHVFkaqCdrHX1KDqa@ANIg1B8JPX3rLnjYxUbqU2V4GizWX@BnRe/ghchLAM2jNWZruZoP5@rSNzHPhaIOfcz0idvnL6osI2uUPkc84UPdgwRUyH9lct75Na3oUFnQxZCU3FYEEClhDzjwf4bZbCifODzoPJyCORZBch0TUkOXvzhmjINjVGNASXynhlXAbaJzCmhw6U5qF/NCAqHVBv9TeSYJ9tCmKgZi2v1GIIF@GVsyvSqXQmRtNx6dC0Tx1a7wld7Yys5lEiDFOPTq3rKXETKt2WooY48LjaOuy8UadPtxURaNnDX1AnD5pQ92VhECJ15Sk9aG59Rc7Lm0iWsvW3p9JIC24mvbolplQuUeR@p2OuiwpEwH1hwXNFNGBS2J41OSerwVkDnIqB8QgYF9deFkW/uv@ILdHd30frP//zN3pA/@u1M4SBAmceQ0cbhm6sKam/trL8pPhCt9UVyyfIp5apE2HIdRvIru5CkXQrdKwGTYvwkgTD/wiXFPwah7aJN5Aab2hmHHO@Ihg8V2eyalHNBpbZXRf3yn4snhUt/4Bi1yMicCHINCgRsS5eCcaML8FEVGxkY7cjFWyaYtSYeb0Pp5Mpv4PgemslmmP83dQ3/ZiZvN5RDYXvXL@hyl39dNpzpPHpIJRTCyviLkpPa8ASiAP@cnAbnauLzwvId4IHz3XRFkObck6P21qFZ0@9sdQhLbzH36gjjG7IwbX4fV0U0z@8FzrWU8206PaeLdGHDg3F3w2h4F5TKUI08wqZLb0zRxlk@OGtLNxZAByn1k2lMtk1S8vj8fr0qElS@nJ5deqZ3OX0WDVHoPD9rBKfRaMC@ztcb6lVGK7MkW5JWi/iXMvMV21MuBY1XNOkNHj4gk5g3NjIcUDqTi3dXbhuaOILPIJlhHUz0v6w8cTsOiAOjJlalFUtGDoiAwaxzGBr3CIj3E5Mt8j2B3MVGYPjJFLoWs0CnO4Et4yuaVPvwdD4Vk3cEBtpJLKzjlJd5xx/a8WHIaim/L56RHu9Eqv3YE6S1bV0GMfXDgdLk4M4@XhLQz03PYNuqwl7uhLRSdda6b/cBYJpv@g03m3N2jMtx2PHdL@JQAMXqMDvqxt0lJambks0GR5138CDgj0OiwrVrYFjFUoDRYfb2lqfun3k@/7zfTlcyKFU9RYOFYg/jq36z7V8/VRxT2@rIDqw6OL@1ojzhiF2FZvy117Wlw4UA1y4W12y@5kSpZQVPtW3JmNccjnX58Hz5xg61pE2GDrGcxKnQbrDBOUSOCYuF7F/ntxyN@fWez@mdA1s8bZCRCr31DJgsKL7tSplWkb9wBRqJvP@LKpvTY2psVLROOq8NPBY/Q1KxvsjlfGLsenP1OPiAB5NCWO99jXD98Iax2l8u5GZ6JbZNW4XZZaZ2hik7zGqzk/A8QQd11MM7Ol4qVaXtDP76c0kG46DLu30lrDDkA/lQ6VbJKUl@dwz6HejxsQ1PNwgVstnMhlfgImsuCy93KRJZcO0L01@X8qYfBY5L@LiKpsbca7Og8gS3YK4lgVp6xR7ilwuK7ZpG5M53t@Tm3Ycx/qQmgKmigeGHdBWJdpqe1ONXRN3/EMkbDF14eGER6e/btKCjza@bgn0QaX5pkqPLgm9V21KuOg5wgWp5debp28iC0y35YKHW3FOiG@@tdbLkv5siCqX5OKNvY5LqE7HsHT@mBVyN8Ery9kb4S0zDX@xFhd3@ZLuYik@doUpjedALLMHWsrQGBn0eoOUr/fQRIb/WBtp5uBvXfDMMLrK7MDoroswNoEv2HhfWkOOCEsTxwb9aoL7/FBPsXAnqe@7jgMHq34riXw40gcGt9lyE6dcTFjgbhqu1i2cq6cuKnwHTReSLYxxrG8S0KlOjbkXPFcCfDTvQr1OR7dPt13p/F2cA32P3r5uC@v1IdYeOkN7aAz5vvHwbV3ngPY44TZ2bkIdsB4McSvbeLy0xT1KT8uxrPehJ7JGzigdp78SpwM8/Iontz4ILj9p7z9unbzTJ5x3oGNtrxkaUxiXPGfijA2J3tZFtXCih9/X8dBgkfrnnUG6Uc8HigTPnxf@rbrlQHcm4zE92mNr6tGNkkp0Zvk2uanPt6bQpkjHHcivnVFH9j1lf98KLYGvZjEdc9Id4qFx3rKNgdPpDs3bkPYNVSjBlA9/fS/dFSljMukeesuWCeR15zK2l1o0/Bgfh@sq3Z894sNa6LhBXlk1Q0fHsqWxftr1@GwoulgFJ4QjvZEf3q7Q8ffKq6k5WQCN7GUKp3f5sgQ61uHu755YK1nRGYkFG/Z3VaxtpSSko0AuGRkQeNR12S7vc4t0sWyW39YhFC0lYRTZl/Ih5Pb3/tDsoBmZtwX/pfa1tGlp5SBnD6cD7zrD5NP1PRDR8LZ@2oL2MkemrGHM0m3/sY7MmqXgIUd4tkHmmho3rqnkb1xUoXiqJemOCY82PKDqpmvn0Cxz7PE7k/prl@L8vUygi19dL@S0ma9Wpv2K6Rl9vgSCrttExJHj4k5kkEGkLq6k4ww6MnMueHHGZTsDYOqSxRaRg7jrxJaV24RWV384ZkqfPzYGOu61fmhOcLPmilZBTXbV9qJbYX99qnvm16dQsnWNDS028GVIN3q0H99WwHukD8zug6WKCJH0Cezv9OSPpeaPXtfr4nxoerijKXTcMDGFTY43Ymx1bdAbVsS8Om8fGqtYdCB@DHJl7FVz6854jqfF5uS6aVrdnNAsq/9cpzqu2wR2IxLn09F46vmP1TjQnqnoLPTolPy9cxOAS6@AtbKhbk1Wz1RHplxBCvMHxYVznTT@hWk5A/ZFKcNAaAMhDIXzFQ3nLgzPT3BDjmuvaImU93sue@JEh@Tygr2CujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgicWho8ceEJBeYh3efdDIUgnqyny8HZZf3E0@ZbxHVresTN1uwY6Q3sjUbXAz9XYD3Yf44kOB@2lnEe1tK5jQfcCh7Wyy3QdezqR3Kl946hQuHFUqKC1qUgzYImvHzx6loy2BtqtfZsUGtgjW7jWbhi40shMGwSx9Xx0OXagS9zjdpKe0lbhW9LsoTGnLrHre84qfefJHAaQ91aYgPlPR/eMLi4b3pr3Y@eRYzswGo2BUY6eGvzM/9JGj9UJMdlDPNUO9Ondms0xgV0zCHFpQx8bHahfa@F6n7GIA76nT/Q1QxHNDZL@F7pubSum1THclzTpF3GvU2mXEXpgzEi3WN9geB@UJt0uF4lxPm6pjyyt2Hhjx7H5nbhtBh7qo5u5CgwFdHv/hXIZN@IvzQus1M@Wi3p0xneJGD1ulGJdWV2j41j8fsOeJNvkewJ01zQ85SHaOCC/Qo5JIH15N/KQ4o08ZKEagSR7pnu0SL9a1ViAVGcfsAVoqLtdB1fCfMcNu3MihgluYdPh3n6@caADhJ8Bx9K7U99Y6G1oWaPOiG5rFYZIbT41OngqqEPWPCb67Hpl8pkh35RBZEdXaAAgYFfYqQss8QS0keTtw9aSHrVMVXNMN@LUa5fLabOOZJtG97WOs2YO0WsxN70UDmVWHpNzzVx1pBvRLLKi00n3lT1peesaCDSWIU2GLuj8yuSm6e3AzMqK9ZDpyMBF5uVVmLWiq@MNqbDO6vX0kLm6huTb@gNeEtr94/KhtLdW8kTw8H909xMFBuF2IReYHgHWdfsKPiA/dW3/8T4t8InjTfrm7AjwxlMA69gJFisPSeDBewa6ttYVAmrPnlp89mEQ2Xc16pE6JpEVZkmyiF1PDMmwzyQyBDe7XiKHH/pS9tB678ToSb4dBFxpkB4G57/CaP5zxQJqlDfiZk9V4YSdFXL@9s9VxD0POAPIW85EGnv0VMbek8OHRyfy2FNXjk97QzwdcU2OWzKsoJUykSmpl7obWe/k29F6pjdR7h6r0v7DQxkjrKE3X9GQ4IErc0uPtfOegRVXRV@rBWGoMVktID44efQwtTiiyRL7Q9cZGclo8P7xcRpPmnxyvDI4mvo@9I6@M1ub/PBAVZMrmu8zm1YH13HPFTmtg3RigDYKjfEBt8tyq3DVdcZG72Q@Nj6FwRM5uPee2RfWFvKxfmYOsBey8lpCUUdlZbmQS0Z2ZoOybbjhc119nppj5JZdeij8sXY7CkoOWcXNrpYeblrxvyrFsIy/E@HDEqmZ6601akdY0b2/L2Kqqq6j87Heh3pl@bWVtRxh1fqw5Zy9x1Ky4SsvUuglTaBVSeat@8iL0ghYt4I3nJ73PcHZWbsN5iYAoXdhZYc/N@y5bku0lnWTeFGB1Lip7cYoXxjvsSAV7vA5Q2PlK9f4wi31LNElZ/KWjE/cSJL9/buHtyV46tPy5lgfP37GnugeGiG5OWIUY@M9MF5IRi8lnLdCC3hrl1N7LoDSboQ3GK/uzxV2rLs9x57Pbl@EozOoOLSTceEQFr5RJMMyZ@aqsarL57WerN5mdFve/BCHM1@Sg6PGaXxA7779z1Q1kyHTQ/hUM/z1lpoJOjhLoEufoz27aNDJYcgauii3yOCRXKmNPjRmuB2FzwavUupXjm@FG8a@YnL9cHJTWOmGsNwN@V0LQ0@WlTPqDQDzN4SxvBwGP3Ss86Ej7@uu4a3Yf7wSoZsKUr6hIOUId/atpdPCou9eL@Lj0QX/sbK1nhgTNzceOh0zt7IMe300MskeobH06@H@dgrdpe0tA8c/8sHfV@d3PjVWZvRIf706gDjN6cogYILGcEpHIq4HLy@QdkDmNeyBye0rsrvO5IDeblDMwhPPq/cimON70/F6jIE34icprrLzpYifgc7snHvsLh6NW4jpK3R/3B@32n@dTMvCiUE0M/rgZC9oXUfHihbJcYHF50@WvPHw6OToOOLnGrPZOqVXmq3TIVeGLHJ9fJJbyna7/vxsBbHWnzcCcQP4cfhcKwdxZvfJ8XWWgOrbcDKygpBPdHsxY7pUYT1nQicNVwY@mc9oG@XKmh7yXWyrwtzuCu8lxR4GZNOEvD2l3UbL@u32ulZ5YnxOaw8gBrEJF0s4UN/wkjHLDQMMKcnajuqcLoSfJXSPx0PTnq0MGq1LQ7tIEy@91d1gjx1bzjl7GFoVWscetNXA9TPDXsecVh1WlMrZm6Ww7BWRal298K@X@I91VXJ3naB2hWfghoibuAmmf9pV7gcvn2rJW@N/chxEvz3uvuXg/H3PnI5uj0xgU6nbI7o3sL@rAM3bo@HHPk6HjmvfHjVoTpXKXeM9kdh475ijedd5Dxw6/f7tkQ485/ZIj6bWxESdZXXUx87UQgsC18L4AWrof1Hj@17aN5/EDQ7wY96eHHwhIZGwoWqTy5@jip5ZRxPViU000bpJ59Mh7ps3bMM/Ew4BYnDK3D8Fj5YcTXtq4DF2/pGaSW0TsqnV1HyZ7eD3nypMzVCe@Em7MjeYF2TWYJsX/gnvSkW9ZBs1JlZE5p@xD@1fcxvOABitz0KhmHSqss0JhGwG58MZfY6EvWE0rQV6tJrPwJusRC1lVP0T9IDT5sWTwycHxyd7J8@OG5nWpX/CPiiFbUNugR2Pj7I9EQrv0w3EZW7RnSw7WJAdfSoFp8O8oFwMP7@0XLTaUtEWhRJ3MM3mhW0rChkZUKRLwE8SeW4UikwfvDjsoMRUQb59iQo/709mC6COOGiR8oRKq7DMqozHOoh@m7YffvVrZRSKX7Or4PfsMGPfCDe0xIHj9PwcPYPdfgU53t87fPjs6QELEFy0mnOzNxnWynluo50bPoF66pu067LG4n6SONRVrRa/HwfCxOU4q5BZCLKPDg0dogXUQYMSfuotltgk@EDBeFgpyn/@hnIZl/EAQRLixgOk4pAttHlqKBsbG@wEGgm79/Tw04OnDPE/uEfeSCIEwU7wTPqf/bjHvzAS2IwKvuTnjkhOI5s7QtQuRWCsYWFPAmlOfXe8/nt@9EUPstoQfkok/BaSINCXZqDdnpO5xyumAJNknYt/f9C31BhkRE0o@CoBrlWh1UXXY2emZ6LNCMShj0YQlxs7bm8jw58y28OPFeInEXX63A2gPrUn3NCYb24oBi1NDnlOmm0SsvzjOGIkYnx7Axp7xwARnnm2CQLhpMJeQkvE9aAKtykiSfX4tSQB6Aq5JBT7IhGvWU30lKarvPu1f6IMqgzcE3B/x3fPMnfh7Vf8tz64f5W7nyvY0K5bWVzgEkUILaP6JeCIhPRH2ke@0WhzOy4LwqExyICxMnME1XRGVMfoPAd@l4AfL@AkGp9CpUFzgxrz7bfw/Ay3lUDTrBVFwSaFaqVMp2eMGd/KesVEayFfyKkKICmdBQDpmwoDPKPPASaTFegmwpk5rr0AVWV7e5uJOLdk1ApVXrPKpv08K74IEd2EuML5EJFrMEgDSRYpIKzuJ4PRJ6UmMSlyr7gaR8bVc2BYonAcvvDd9gkhsgQQi9PIQCP9M/yc5wQkLt/UcAc/gBn53s6mD0hSYUwiV1IUfMsnj50JNB/opIsvanHLJ7iVmw@BaMPT4x@5JQu/2B7l6z1rcWA/@LCP39dk5AEcVDZzdTSN1q34GYI4RhAVcVXzbTxnzUnTbim8bTJopj9c0ZhtcP@yMljTZnm5967bd01ctc6KxGK7x7aDk2j3oTAsoSlaVlELyUWRcrmVRfJL5GcDxUEjUm8gO2BTwDK6hvnSGXt7@weHnxw9Ob5mw5Rixq9GA75f3041JTndaIWOeLRYy1Vy975y/Oju/aAiFkgXItwYGL9fEvWmkizmxhHk4qzV1aKtwvBq6dZj/Bm3xnAV36x2E2qU6BoeauYD8qXzDtJ9OrV4NXOttIpa@fxNKC3gKRHQ@/zI@TVUE8mLy0Zru960Y/HrLWFFR3gek7ewE4Cr6W1tKtjYrxcOCxZ@fvoEP@znRftidnVfFDezaCIPLV5MnNOFEUHfIxIQKW@QDbBIQVaCqGt73xEX0hemLjX@eWxuWy9qOSyCcCFzE8UjoE6CL20jF1kY6vVt1A51b2iZHSGw2MZt1QYmNUMztdzaWiIp@J974Rkn/G9vzyozmTY3JpLI7QhWmt1k9jaAlxSgQ6N092TqDdkTZ8zN/9MmlntG4HrqAPu9N@WTXgb7ZDqCeH16PDVoQRE4twSJgZLxEFUuSwGX8K3ezlJoVxjya6DtW7/g8qiXT8yS8tCY9cwB8PZEMg0c7SNVbbHQMi4Wmizh2nGR6mxRCzd2xY/RkECU7B9kHnm2QEBv6LJp94xZIn4eT1ZakD/6x88/O4snxVVticw0@3aLe1ftNYfoF9WbOYk@8XtnYAx5Fbcol69zCfC7CpjbDQy@PVYuy0NPoG9J1lByP564D8EJYkSiP9LHLDG1uc1FmdFropmw02SMTqpze642S6VIoYIHBciMUvbJxcfvhG7PWUKp4edGwdeze/h4bY5ZQ5XlFrgpkyTbxG8C7oPEhVZIkwIowZCkQmBr2IRAzQCMeCeReQOHNBgOceFBlitXBNMn0mjdxUGaUKlZ/Q6LfONxWXIUy@WKX6HLXLHMoPVdZ4eyAmCv8blArgfq@uaYgGag/spCbMHIr3O8GOUb44g88O04ATqxiA3mwLwTA1gLC8ndoYu/xIENfQXkg0rl2cn9dimpiCy0BzVwzR6uC/LPCIQqnv/hJ@imylLUeJVrdB9jMrS82eYGp9AA5H3qMOIVlhqLksG3Xhwoy96ibarqja3eT@jXAsTM4QDgn5ttB@DQWmowYbgibDWz/9nPYihsJDZV9bTtnqXi@UwVbmo1z/Lso82mJG02MrXdTR20qMmrWRN0cmUrd@/MGPZ7hwOlKYosy3KKsnVxcRG/v/XEfJ5nBalnaoVXs/lltpB9NbvMqqVXp2O10JBfzVpiqZY@bbEnTz5/236bFGdn81diM6HF9o/eiGoOVf5YpcwudgrZ2GkZ1E/Il7FT9hqu0z7Df3K/7kXcOro7fVBh4yKLNZtAcVUsiorSiLfgn9T9F3Bxxb9Rl@vyTuvt22RD1yezOTNNc@z1evBzhiBBasljBvryHeD0PIHCmvQkDQqv0ax/fT4hz9hszxgMpgd6XcMj1fJuuzo3p/cnj774LLie4fX6aSTZa/8jxKlUQpIaK@YpKm09H8PPGf/ZTzYu0xdP2tt/9s2RYmzg4wgf37l8hO5jNf/RxsZHd@/mcmlN07j7yRdPfnFvby93L51/0sjv5KTMxvaf/snGhqZta8pGy/PUVrxxevq5qGVyovxnP4q3nzz5uufVs//nN97WVbwV4XbGisAn4MoyFZx4L8FPRRnrfa/Y6xi0cjU2p792LPC/2GBqfaf4X7539Co2idU15TMXnpPYq1ihFONOcMBbNng7i9Vj2xitcBmbK7VaDZzF//JvIX39E4CDIfNtuNXzAazCPFaXapTkTaxeAIeqaZDv//2Nb0Qw5GyiRmJccO2yBlxirqiJOy24tujaFtDOppRRlCCePRlODIeppTvqHXwx4QUetoEfLDAmzRh@0J0d7TL2tJFKpVpyW4JLfk6TRIqqak1VvQPsQPpoq1aTthi3JJrN5u@gNfQkTWkNHBgxjTuf/UNcsVWe1Z8b3FMhVtjYfXGvXocyZevZrXqKLr8jUZ8qlkTH2RVZmr2IgwrSaL14yLj547qYKWliOp3ebdP7DGklzcKWhBe/x2KhD3ZZdtVvKQlE8X1jHx4vdoDXn/9vf/79P/8e/X2ffv8BDZHaPbOvbEGkM@gSdbh2K5VuvS7WXfGiie91aEeZSqlSUtqXzcQWcKDWU6ZmPn4Tz2fjx/xj6ypjzSSlhouyrfvZ43s9tvCuc5961M8P4JHJg/mlIMcS1cgdUu1aPBha/S3bUuOs3pJQIKpJDbWQb0k8VT24yqyxC9UkasWy2Kpree2I7bZn/GLDTY85MdAMCwEdfXzri7LVw5DFWz3qFasHyeqLOB8aL8RXiDUaSsugASHwY7sblY1SpVDRlHZ9/QVNM/pKUQ3DeOLFzmLhxSkbWxA0FjbNq35BVYQvLGjB7EPiQWW9z2Q31VK2oIpV36W1mViFRqJlJW3QFjOqGPY2nN@HawP@6B@u8BXvG@Tje1OU69cGq6hbWlbJf1Q40HB8veWK4irAOMG6nU7ndbcDUoeud/Surk70qT7T5/qkM@3MOpPutMuwyyzP6GedvFNyZow3QFmKZfPqZuwONeq3jQ32lHOhFksFVzN16/VMltu@kxwO/iTJmcWE2D/AVVc1lW3B@JSBGwhl5ASdGf9UVWAxELQuWm@3Gm@3oIPWU9vEHFt1yccSHnJ7t5WSLi8b4K5W/f/teuis0sVdULjWZSq1/bwO0sfzeiMFIJ/7IGWJEVC5XW9tU0iYmZ@bH7zdAvlFSm03tmvOPv1k6iBSPOfEC85uCwBvLyG7u5uSwbULAOqb0B@TqdSmJG3g2NjwxwqI3KqnglIhDgmQFi4ufs4fKHrQiy@3L@uXje3Ly@1t@N@m@6X/BN/L7Wv/9Fhca@IswlvIWpoNpd5Umj6zaMG7rNTRR1aa4KjDE@I1slqp1UAHXHLrv81/Ob24hz6IcksGrIXYFtuKoVnMbGxLiL149@X/gr/muy9/H@VFBn9GRYhdYLdWtlDbLHOlE27MfmSzR/yywY2/4BV90ONRHT1tfrNxQUpRXsiswuf8E2qpkJRxAG47/TZa2pDZC4h6jfcxUSsVxHZKnWssti0WisTufuHaFY/H/9ELrVyM84kaNBXxwvO8RxEsF3hC5KqWUSX1TZ1/DYF/uOYXVl3/6BfWXULsTZkZFaBPgnHCCDFoRzFFkSQYsOrbIzxLgEslEmqlZ7XPpWd7Ek6j6BNaCOvyKYLa4UGtXK7zVZ7NJ9Rrtu5twV2F/4MNKAZr9iFus1/rjkAAbvazea2JpvNjUucV/j18jX/spIt/T1/hHzt5jX9PJ/jHHnXw7@QV/u118O9khH93X@Hfo9f492yAf82vZLNqVdy8IMqk1LJ6uTkTiULV2E69@ZWJO69Yht0wey3/q1DZXJklY82vGLOuMZ5UuGc//tPvfvOb8VotLsXpWzs51XGZmqwC8aFEXry6GxdiNbapbqoZK9PNqB21Aw6TZVyWGWaGag/0lLbKMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9cBvxlwGVm@iwzYBk7Y0NECAXXpJ2ZoKsPjwH89QGQC38mbo3tqJkug4wslNnoM50IHlxv2k2hweJMfGGAqimrckYumC38uFFDfPGiqWy1tHKJydim5HbjRTPeEpsiGrzXyjnWmRsbzRcijMwZkbc99GExzwP9tRpTmk2FkwkoQFS8vGy3Dx7fa7cVHIWaj5yjxf/R0Sj6euP/6Mh5dOSMHPg/OjqCnmPUU7sp4M@7uzXg1/5jJ1av7jQrxPUDzh9Ttnea9ayE7kIKmLmGfqkPvBYQ4VnfaArxc9AfzkH1qCZAATmvnlWr5@T4jL@Co41u9Az/z32H/yQI1VB9OYfrjMDSGzrPP2uGLu5QPjsHr88YqF3hP@h30df/Cv/mf1v/j56xJEs0WsnExeV2gq4k/iWTF5cXl/69nkwk/JfENvyhB7xjkovLOjop0gW4GolkK3l5yf3gnkhuc4B1yGa7TmkX8WBUiIVZUrb8lviv@4Ss/asZr4LYy1XrfIb6UUysMn2xrabZnGUyyWon@JYHLhLrb2jvQrJKH3Lc7DTU1p/@iL7XspOkSPlctapuMf6i5bRqNRe8FUvVail42UwkytevemZHLYD6kcslk9UqvOwEYDPwCmkb7G2K1VgT7q07d3gmJe3NmwBmNldIZXA7U7Ua5JSHbA1P7/oM9@LwiD51AqwmH8NvDHFWksjQh5LwY3xxsSLeuZPoGbj/urezl7xzRytn3rwJfcZj8FKXvNrtnum22@ifffNGbIu0Daach/dM6c0bNVNOqfGk4yYe41ccIauEpLKPtDrlWgY2ruWKEOwjkN/eLuTq9UIOfAqleBKX1BuIfgvwjYvxqhi7oDKopSLngGIVvaPbg6Av46DALi5jVKEsl08mgJEmQQS8jOGfizyXDzf5fBIocynymGq5zKMmWa6QKKXK/l9tA5RykHH4Hwpq2VRuq7i1CyIv/nmzVRfy5OqFUVMvaxdGBSfVL6td/3vYaC7EuHMnWwYSlTLVptBu39s72Wu3a6IoopwEN/Qk7i6gFRU33qCS58stTpFKdZeqWS3lGdQnjyPFYYRgJSC6om3l1RISSTD7aA0ISCJwZWmDbQgaPfEmlDnlNsATtBnIvAcX67EOG@DFBqi7MZNZdDGL8XC6d7thJIdffmj4SmlJvQt8jPAS/F6Y5U0UBvEnD/f2D07S2rbEYtr9vf20dvzsbkzF1/zinYKz@P70YO/e0TNI8OThwd7xwceHnx48ewL@HjtfXAHT9@@LZ9S14v2cfSa8dF/rhqEbU8Non0@n56/YS9Nsm1CZ1hQK5Qxc5hltKMtYX5SrCr@u6ekvX@rumC727offfvfD/@7d73z33e98@93vfP@nX37/2/D7Mfy@y5/f/TflPN5/@uU/@913v/074Pkf4PdH8PvJT7/8jW/wH73/Mfz@U8Tvj/1fJB7/CQDrV3765fd@9NMvf/UH8PuX/u8H13@/9pPVv@9/a/0P033vd2@O891/C7/f47CCuN/9be6Hz2vxf5vH@9UfvPsX/47//6n/h87fefcv/hhv/ss//cGf/qd33/z3mlb603/97lvfe/etb7771nfefesfa@9@41@rmejtd999/w/@6g9/76/@8H@k/x/T/ffe5//dD/7pX/yvf/G//8Uf@r@fwO/fgesnf/Hvoav87R/8EP@/9wd/@0c/xP//@V/97R/8@t/@yv9Ejt/kjv/nX/4bfv/rX/uPf/Nb3/mrn3zjb379J3/zm3/wV//Hr/5fv/Ef//q///2//iffRM/f/Mlf/dGv/OU3v/2X3/rnf/nNL9fcv33j/cv38P/yH8Dn/fF8HzjvU64P9fny58Ln70ONRS7QTqB1//K73/glaOD/grF33/4xHrSD35r/H2sqxfkxf/v/gEO7XmYMyYALfr/@7tvfRRL9D0Ai@A/p9Z3wZSmEv3xn8QJk/a0ViX75p1/@8x/RW8yo1GnRBsfuklZKbYF@s1Uu@@O3v54DSX5pGVoIwM/pO8ihlsK@g7zt3Q@/8e5H//jdD3/z3Q9/BQdvKVdO76Ul9ZbFMIiYf494GLHwPvEw4ueYf4pm2KTU5/DGPvcDP//8c6H9RsETnbtvwPdz8uIX40F44tMPCsLQH4@Asjcs6vadGd@56fuGOTPWePGihcut4Ie5p0j22ApEo3yWzVI@YjPGV3XQHyLNtsg5wzv5YvBMwNvif@GcCSw182d74ZlaOMnhp/Oz4E4hD9mkZuFaEslqjEtHW9yHlokp31yZYQlms9QMlGBwQA4pCLoL4nitlsKENY4PvHLU6iVGqKRSNSg3puZp0u0SgpjdJSiQspZ6ytpbtRlPmEJ49YAcKQG9noqqJqZKtXuQYW12jyEsBE5gX7yo1Uu1WR3BveX0SM1SdwknBFZLzepv4b1GMCGdELv3FlAp1VKpegkzxELy6km3eSXlqXBU9hRL@XUAT9ztv7PL2EeiWhL5GsEGEozHxntqERsjQnQIb6a2/OLQf@Ck3xYRfIOy8nNhPHyHZNMdLq5iBIArSbIsM/jh8vsO24XgGQeVomzhkeIQUtQiqAWEHgznh1JCiuo3RS@Qf6y29cEXAsPCbG5uCrG6mBWPZCKdojD3tEJHH3A3IKoXFSYWyiJ6G3QOJMAF0lcp/804rqvFGQfMPkrx3@7uFvsIiknPhZ/ApFTWyTkxDmU7lRI1gF93UsJzUEsEaKcE6I0gz2q0jpcS0mnG5FoMw9jR0ZGPBHk8rwkpaOZaVsV3XE2aTqcxSCHLaTmd9p8yPclD9h0yhfpPeROJS585Z5qWq4L2VGXoxaKqjgoqMHq@ffsWaoW2V1UOQflk/k4rLVeiQPDghm0sax4cGNJyZYFr5kwt5BhL0AwrXEmGJ2MS0JCSAt@Wz9EIrkRcK5XiFBPoLye2gq13BZUaBE6wxuqIanBxpbCUTwaB@0ds/@jRo4PHJ@NWiwkGfbjdaI9dp2t4XgLD9h7f40cytHIhGWs0EPRJRUMWIxxUMsSOD@89PTyuMF5svxIShFiVFlb9gpZVITYef7Yd87ceifjtQUc8xntlUbaEVs5C0lhdiHUN1C1wxRxV4CqrCo@8wV1nBlp9WhTTagF1uySuDwIev@hMGVrG5WZ0oFfhQQ15e5soINQvJFq7QCfUV0Go1/1Ne0wV6scHJ5Dg5IipWkYW6p@zmYwZSpdC3apZhj2YDDdx95vYzIiRMm02Mmn807JZuKu5QlrNF1sbG9aFhHk2qdoucBvjJbxeSFiMr8LFhK8K7KvgBRfkgXsTmb8x9PCo6u/OQxt0Cb5FT1Tz0NGSAs5kc3DCOHpVoX0vrwQJsY0vvpiweh00bOnwvhADfjFkwQY1yezJQ5mquTd1DQodMNYzPzXxo5Jyz/TGlj6HzgPUiF1eXvYB0uF9ptU1euUpeni/7JJPB9yXM12I2ZVK7a2aKwraaaXyNqtpAngIWwrugNuABkAbCbYU/lf1IJNstqQAr1JFER7ZbFbA2WNBqBgCo80ibzO1msTbYDan0l4RAb9Tos9qWnj5cWcfLeJmMzwuhkAAG0xclgnCijzMfysI9AZEw@1x9FXsqt89M3fuZHEaI5vLhPMVVGJ2CXWzmc1lkeLC/3/hCSy@nrM9rmcz6rYyBqcOzty2ooOzA878ttIBpwnO8rZignNaz6qZbWVaF5iwza3QMjRyUxMnxgyNXnM/se4ZVl/Gw0U1kTLQxG3fqns9SFjv1XpOlz5pX@3Jpm0bLh5J5wlyObHq2GgfsYaWUugQP0skL4RB7ZwOzgtGbSCjyR3X1i2hJ3ec3lz2JnMLj@lYjluLg0AYDwIW0A2QRHD2ayebzVUarCWPnfGOoOWLqYaagSEEf2opraU3jJ1isdKTu5ahuzv5Sr6U7uEJIH@RayefqQzkzx89fDCZjJ8adCxoJ1eGBGikDs1J7ZQq@Xyr0RDFVIOyaeEHuTl7kjY2oE8bek@CJy6BeZJWakHinunWavH4TlbVJLWSzZQuhQXhkOZYwrqASVNYsjTS/cLnABXbsYHZVNJ62rwgKlT6/f7l1kVq8SLoFxJ/A/pcSnq6cxG@VqVIvAqbpiVzEQg@eh/IfeGv7lVELV8Sq43q4r1YEKutS2F3ZPRMHU8DNTMX11MVgClzqDHIqMmEy4rrOJNKx@g7rrGImFULQUSO0PUIOfEyzK6ZwRwvrmdXiESaXVyHksuLl2GqAC3h8hLozokNZPdNDNdp12xDLedaB8CCoPlsB9aHMVrs@XMhtvX002y9DlV9kStquXwur2ULhXxRg/GmnCvkS9DZMoVMXtMASq5cKhcvoV0rytsYfVyQ7V8E7b1Cn1dI6BVuH7TRYsm3j03ropSVOB6JZPXyMvZWiH309FMNBsi1VwIG3U81qV7L5svgyqJLywLCTNA0SctKWVVSs/h/i0PD//ePr8G/hndIldWEEzQa9BiGTRjqbfYQjY9MHHbi4OenBuyu0V0TY3@o05bmfdfxvL9HnLu6fcqD7pncUm8Y9EDHb/B5I3MyXBPj2XiE9oYM9x8MwsGoAwgiO@QR7sLNtRxnVYQie/ZkTSkfhbbxgRjcOD5Ef3r48YOTyPPkYG//gVBgd48e37vyyPuR8uzhwf2T8LXIQ4Ok@RDELx48fHj11X/kjp497U8dF3/C/aNnucUt9MITs0IOruVIoTcB8W/4SoIlSBSgiuWLgUMV8JzFHVCP7/jOfGHhzKDzM34c2PTCff/8ZHhFOAnOCOsMOW3HYF1uVgr1dTL56MvyarEsCGNmO@esmGE9x7J0lzn9/gZ4DnU872igQGtZ2BIx63PHtXrnZs/YEB7h0cqyih9vRySEBwBkNO2SxQIQZtCAMIxqNsOFqY41Ndh0zNZ6wgO90OmagyGMwedOEEHo6DqD34dekN6IXpObPSY8D/K7FmJdjy7EhN1YKS@K@6L4QJ/o9aprFJ9XvUylosbjT1yxLI5hWNa9gXEwg5bLnkFP0t15WpzI4n0mt2MDXN@wnDHqId64AYJ7WWu0dnJavZTJZ0t//Vs//rs/@fVBTW1m9jPS9s6jh86EvS2mUJqoePkKMDuQaxmJrr54K5Oio5VL@VI5q5XSpXIpl1cL@Xxa1dKgJRbLoCZk1JJaKOXLarqUK4NckitDaL5c9IVjJZCGla0KgLW7@HnxbdKV5CEoRXxpkr1O6EkW08P3KRMNSCMKqJhO6DT5llmDIZWpGZYtMoCosy6L3b@/n7l/XxTv4gtu7djPiGIPX/KlTKZ4VxQNCtkvoYwlOjxNCQ01ihP@ksncBZpPOQD8xoEoDvHloIBTbKJo4sv@3v37mE8fXzRMD9FOeQh/sYKXIkSz8QVkdgLwKoQG0fZ4PjlC9ABfMEsMuc9D9iFMFD8O0MGQpzwaB/AgKOnenige8pe9PQzZp2LnOaJfw5c9ukTRhRfoDKI4AMfAhW4oih1wYpcQxS64unMd/PBT7mgG357oojjn5EECieKMYuvdU1FsB/6Yzac@NnmkboVeVF7qXXop458oagHSGC0bvmRFMRe@5KBsDx58qg8nPWPAr7nLn10o6YMHWd2cTQ/udz7@uDMYdNz53sHHTzFof/8ByCfzqdsZdPyEnTZcDqTaf6Dpp6P51QtKfdhuV3RrZdDX2u2cbl8Jas/bBmIIqV4BZv41wIxG7X0I2n/Q3tVXLS0TwDZygxE8O3jdHcHzrt7hQcFFQfScdTpiFZu/ojQTAmoQuCiM3fEUuKudHuld16ni@6zGMmkUYuaNQqZVpQA2Ak0gU73E8H4C7zrOByUv5o1ZLdOqzWpFje9N6ifE5kzLm2J6Y7SjlvOVDX1H1XKpWQUNWjj9OItL6g5LqHe2XrPE4@SOBlqB2NzZkcSG2trR1FKlUHy@NRXFZAXvO9li5XUiE88whrdko9jaKeYjKYrFlK5olWIRZDOgyQSG@A5O0rQTiXNDP00mEVuaMoAiUFnZnMppVvuJWXpW43ixebI6q6lVbv6ZZa4B6@G3BqbdieNykAMAN9vJVHBVPiGq5ZIICChKIpkMmR5o8MJiV@hnXz85PTn5nITAuj@b8cQ1kHtV/dePH@zLh0fBG34lQL6PsqnjyvvItZZCuJAaeJ2AViI/gGEVNLzADw8Ouo4lH9BuOhBwg4DAUJHsW@yVTx4swTkeOuc8Z7S7UCWzj3bXYPgRBbPH9FodXHqPJQgrpifPaUBv1@u1dm1EpgmgiEGqrzH6wsACzKHHcQ@tQVDyCzxM5we0a5nLaqc2i80ATrvGJPXFyOm90FLdag@/nXC3dhcTV9vw7FSNmuG6jiuCfi1W@zt2bWp7et94Yrho5@TwaBPECzxhl@gzI7nJmgcYex91l0up7jJ7gdnj6SihS/VOctkLZ@pCDyRO4utBoS/o0Cfu27is9mss8RyivoJ3d5MlevLd5E6uCnS6y9pJ8Mq86L/oM40VclXSPRIIC7oS0QfLrbNkrf41eHDYp5UKYONX9ClAxcwAsNmjAIg9Ni@r3ZrFEhKbsSQRKVcd1BqY/A3etiVRbElS401LqEvSZ0Id@mt1HtNr3rRDn91hmY6qZQrVGfipxVx1CNWrP59V3dp46hpVC179CT5@vlWvAlGBdgDm9ZvEu1/6RnJbyte4X5VAvbFAFGnL7dqsaqMhT2gYtWwNAlKNXCYNWj3cimkY87VCWi2ks@lcWiqiLwz46XwaPEHrAWEjYSVExsR0ZpaR1bRqqOlE5oXZe5FMnyZAiCGisWR64hzY0xEDH6gqbJv0Ck8gT0rbskAb6zlM35aosQLLqGLBgOpDNjbTQwT11NAtSpFMSiy7lbA2Exhn82Q6Pmi0KpWD2fjrEJSQXu0UUsVM6nUyWU1sJGue8UqoV4U6shcq9XgDWq4/98m86agBtQwutahVGo0OFrGYSWczWSid2X4z2BbrYiud2SioUEWXjNgG43wjOh2IEs/Cb9xGadwyoOrUslYVZJqby5Y0qazkt/IZPj/IUwpjn70hJVmiKQZnuRPxeFGLx5PxKq5NbIj@VDTwNOJnceCu8TvqjgjCmFgRyxpGWLBGOq6bCbADcexSQAmR5UDZvRAuLy6368JXhGM8hLmtPce/4vNHe0f49xXwKsNr6fmjZ0fPju4LTKHtnyBuVjeqcrVdhRdJru8KsQpjwEmbvqEpZYOxD91YmtquP@fPJh4oALgCGedusBZt@DJM1OTYp2jEYIfFoQy6O2poWrbV0Iow9gE3DaJqmlpF000xPLIg1xU6opYrZumImhCbXQCy2yny/xqbz/WUFMwF3GG7g9QmP3JTFrcxXcFPxxfSNjHRWfssxnBv@vPqWfU0U94WiLixK5vYq3u1vcHTvSoTs8WiWN3bb4NTTLBYVcz7QKu5B/Gn8ZP4YXw7WRdLBfIt7@IU@OrJijpIV6enqn8sqJhpi9UYa4t5//xd5OxQTtwuNwVRxF13sYt4LH4JfwsUn78OjhYVAMZpZvs58MNYiE4yFmShtcXnzKueSmpmG5rMLp2v1Pj5ShYLT1ji@rG/9JPNFViyHKzLfCW@G4vH47gAUvG8t@HhPR@8Gm@L9RjLqNJpNbbNxFJAmdeZ06pYLPhvZTHnFzHpZwLaJrbp4Ozb115o0J1ithN4gIaJs38w3OfzuN4QU16MvS@0UvbR4ZF9z70fOYX1HBEADPBIWbXyvL1xqkI3yorZ03SM7cboGIJYhvw17gEkP2Vq9TmSnonP7h09EnNILtDVwCsBpeJYJxOYb3PjzYaDa0ws3Pv41v7k64yN49lcnLFmLTar5fxN9Wq9LqnbGhq9K7IKjJt9tSBl3tQ5Z6hTQEGDkHe/9IPcbLsE71pGhXdNy6e0el3d0lgyNn735e@j@aKLg0/3HrI4rkz83Z/8SCv@3Z/8K9q@F7@k1QotW4xBTHSqhWLs4mJ8cXEJFw/Lx1oxjlSumAQ3XzlTY3VF1bK2bVdZRdH1rWIqp@3aVcWPqxbVZMyTYv6O1WwhLyUSqgJYbWVLmSSEvfFjapkSvAVrdjy6WIC6ggIcPDXzmrq7vQPl28nmtOoGNDo1PNTLwr9twyvHhFjp0Ys3jMFLt94bDEyNXIrCKm8ltv1W2mZvccXsrbTBXtTquPdCxaPAwYrSFh6NxHXVeD2lbMUZ6Jms3risXrZStCQFGvpzw9iym1c6Y3MDz8Yse23Z8GdsefSHiQIPD16DN2PrpScmtpKK0uuJ1zv5tsHydWgwW8riwDLbChaa@J8kNZPvfuk3NK3wd3/ya2/ab9qfa6Crl8sFVYv97GfbU3vqGb36zwDADaZrAn2bRG60MYOOUE9n3Eaq6acKHXJXFGJTG3USHj/Q2lFPZyDPmQPb6JHWLpyhDEqV2@bWE3sJiraFli3SpNOQtbJkVRAC4Z/rLO6gmyYYbAsN@zZaSeFC@CoGgYjDQO@pCl9dgAKPEQg1TrftWVN3TGeLEpRObaXZHUgCOXwVLVNukEUOf3yU1CpTtq4n5Sh7RDWSV9nI8Dy0cwlDu/BVSOJbP7fmbKyj8RiMadowIMsYhfCkgF4D8m5B3hZP0CbfBJWeR0gzjh1PZINeI3wVRDSiggmSGzO3IUIVWMlXgQBQhoQP2GyxbZZNsgszlaoujGhe4jEINPOpB4YrBEyG0HpoKCVIXMV44AX6FH5vF9uFX8MgOEc8AyAcBt81UQONDJPTGwrDZFnmvUEBLLLilqCisTt3FljVamYvyahECP/UHOMMI9WDvRpXABZosx/1KmKaoXnSauAbNjugeIrQhVYncbuk1UhSJuLrpSDA/3s3WmyRV6qKAqpYAL@@eK/oAskgMZKd12GXbdeYqhWTLES@C7h3CSkyHxCq6M3ZR7L2eRB4CRj@LBZ8zQqY1kl01tZvt1ctlzBQYKb4KSG0X8eZgW9xhFuoQ@Z3OAlSh6mgKKZFsfumC8ojbecIjGMmsmoSky2MiRIexMe1HMPzAvkkPigVxmbw1NHIo5/PBhmn6jpQod7YsckqJFmtwsMa0CKAR/kG9TjaU/scPz3n1w0ljmLkkTE9bPmIMVm5dND8D6XF3RQd19BPA9qkmTGQWXfUY1qZJaihkeE/OwSXpESEcAd0EKRxxzJGgNKxYdAJP6@iKAOQS6cdsn74yIR2Nbxvwghke8o9TmDl3Dw1lRO0AS05fTwIyG3JxFCUxe7HN274lgYtxzlllnlq8Mn4xJIlHo@BFgaKRBoou/gBYSu4J0jLpnEySE3zWPArwqPInaV0JO1GYp68/syqG4k21ugbGm9MqBXLONPtCH3peiP40w/e3AtseZFFKniXQ5Zr@FZ8anG0zxGapxJ8q2Q1Mogl4yLPOCHGxMCaFzqFsWucMZxIEHCMAabZDeziYC@G0n6VBgDqe9Cz0MjnxK2gNSfAxO0lutD1fAZvs49YVhMwIje15ptFAxhY9bVl6BAGSbEc3qQHFSPTygbyFeidox6EoR0Rv/lh@qB1o5sMsC6aN9vwweGgQ3nVGO8WwUs@8oK9A9szFX0DAguA4QpMNhJiCsCmxKTIQYfprybnrV0gXlJh1yGlGULwSQ1QSFTQkeWgFcfIN@IECLire/xDIr4J0PPzc5ns0k5dUzY8/G6a59i6pYwHJkjfjjIxRmP/C9VmVxkHcBcuiX8uUR4PxzszlG5r5Ttz/hSEvlfz91Ul4n0vjoPjGX4WbDAiG3ZoPM6jBnXfpE8KdhP@Ni/e/rRW@iJofxVsf1IpfolAQHUDMLP0PN1NA7B0p3ua7p/3qn7AGXVIAA61aASeaC3aDV5GXuAyx/0whjNBPhoGdaxTWioHSCKfNV9kzUsYxJwHr/772JxBIts4Z3uuq88TFJ7E2NiAE3MSe9gchn0KAScaWb/gpovNWWPeWko@C5PDoBZuFHHRQJ1wcTNQbscaw2c8fAbhMx4@W2QaZNuYtbhIhl6XWBxs9WjXNIiJYOZBnEtu83kRQpBBHgetivww5nzJ7xJ@3RqlDujN36Aea0HDgDYxBoIbCaXxvNlotmzPON9qpZQBNHaRCAE1DqAbLaLpeS90I/WtM2vseEteNpqzhVHJxxu9ukO/NfC2gmUMK4gaBqeXiRZIByN/RwsXCPwCAwSUwyAQRYO9ScJMVkPD6RQIDachLmjMEWv4yLRI@vKDfD8QlzjpOWGjgFoRQOgfFgnQhBAW9Bz@lcyAO3zmOhAniCvRh/1GaAkv3ooDJa90Fc5rqlRJEawkKUATyI7iau1qUYJwqIrGlaBIMS/9@o@iv/HB6PehX6zGnhosHzCqQrSr4CZSECH87kJUZfVapF4BA2VLtwwXRq4DLp/6ozVks6UEagbPB4vgnZuT7jARqfxuktcPHVYVbbESNoV5rQZFnNd4t@T9IiApJ3iYzPOTzYOG4KfnDARgZFYmM/xks2iyWa3GGQebrUl2HkFyRkjOeBIee7YGyZafDLSnw2B4weppgXSKu1xFgKfyYRTEoLHIPP3MwH0HL9FKJ67U@HkueA61Ar8NoYiN7azbWpl7I4J0hGldAYAN8RqAHv/gdkW4yvBUKXwLeRQnZcCj@JvfDDivgAZGLLjKLVknwkZGOjAI/GKKxgHou2KqIYgqzbbjX4b/xHTgGfzU656Z5ZjqsmcmfeXvH8SzhZSNdNCI9KFmcsiQUZN5ZvsmYKMyR4ztTUHBAamuc@6wxAphG/yVqZ9U6VhORxnpuH8IP8PLfeXxPBnoD7hexXbHzkSfOLlchStNJjW7VflzncEc2A5@vStizR5kvZ5jeHZ8ApXadQa26RlphoZGTw1f7TD872sIUTnZdzqeIPg72bgai6B5u0JRt902bXPSbidwg2iyEu52p/2i2DzjcQH1X3BF0gN78oEejRNO56XRnSRvh4mfZvCTnZjd08TR2A/Eydo9BjysC/I/hA5BgmGes9Acyew7itKdSYK@NzJ0Rs4ApL6pJwuY@gr4wwVsREgfjwmXNNNRpa1EPtBBvSTRTetJP@nXPjgp@5qW0JNhem0ZwBIx0sy9SmOkrLsiu/ba7HiyIL/jD8f3OIrv8c34khZ@FWeumtd44IdlnU0sIEDEBRrZ29HAogPf6l1DZwmV0BvlKp7gvVHs0f68HmK6B1H3/OhyH9pHOnzz4C1E/NN19L@5AoPkB@9bfTp0e3Y8B34zwq2uCfrgohcsOycg@mESec/17MKm/f929/17beTKnn/jp1BsMrhDu22TQBITMzFgEp9DIBdIcrKE8TR2G3pibI/b/PAkmc@99499gd3/9xH2Ve473L/2Kc7Wt0rqVtvGkJmze/az@czg7pZUKpVKpZJUqtq@Z12UF7Fud6BCkBrLgqsHj9U0MAe07I7iDWQD@A6eh0ncFN@znVxVEmfgNLxy1eeV27tou9kOuv44aOd1TteCa1p8QAs2llf3azgEHQu9vqz18jR3OXEqTeMgumSq3MIyvnvlOLezlWQJY@7hnXLGsHE7/ZA@JZqxxVeV3WpaBywt5bAdexVi@3MwHowlKEJXou1pOSrzj/QkHG7cTRCig8yeZTep1pknPg/ycZPuMSPEeb10k@Gz3ECEH6vpPvw@Et3dUupcq1DV9HImHQ5odo@H83rc4grDk3IYdT@WvIvp7s1zFqsJsESEbX3fFDIFGbYyrVbehihf5vZYvzclE/CN9@l6t8wqzRkCNS7Jkm4U8nKb9Qsng5Vxg36x4fSefgHwLBg1haFM27CnpQPYKk658AeW1qK/kJJOUCwqCsk1GlaujHmm7F@@xXW2bq2zNVVnK1VnPALSVVqZMq1UlboX0D3zuqAbdEa3SGckYe1MP/PENv3r9f0hdiu@LIVLldBVS1dLFRLIS8FSpZ4nobzUXqps80O0VDnkh89Llb/SQzK2lr4uVcywQIYhvfLDS3zXIhzvraXKVt75lhn5n4PI1OstVeI@pTw/yitThEiBdpPWiCO2Xl83czQMaGJjpdJV4JjIxfKJ92Fc/r9E/0mALw79g0TscT7izGpZlVOThjVjSD00bZjQEjNGckXP5vX9HbY1i7OgmmVa49llGDyp4bmltDASxJDKJxr0SwhCblZmY6Ssmeye6OjaiUO5k9P1M/U81gfaeU4/pswnSSUc1U2XN/2VBiEdeD88Ufg2PKfQMdUxRjiTdWagBaL@vDSnUejrNC669@0e4r3udCbCtmCySC8xWEumkw7Hh3OobNAfpJmEU3HLIbTL8KacDEpw70Qxlgp6ZN6SzJ91yyAY7MHvzGuOVQ6opUQQEo9LJzLK4nmBZTGSEllnaaoy@AgFS@bQCA9anzli3rZ@5HwiblyeK26bhkxZqZIlV1pMUmEPDsQu/ZHUHi9e63Ar9n3LV1PyBnsteQCwSsa1iHztf4f@3hf93SjUhggTFcxSrGdPpdPq9dxZdgLzblLtdAci0VXbzkzlKK4hITmtDizNfB6vTan4MPkQJV8qjaFPaPuGbPGa4A66Ta4tBBa0hOFV@uPnFfr4eeV2Qk1rJN0rzygtHmrScKThMaZJ0@bjKg2f1cVI4f1tv/vdHTxMd7DdeYDHDRhOkFxG@fCyx1YuydgmsS1fIFLLFSWCnI9L425OPpK456Pb@NiWPuw3D7b393Y/0qT79OlTR8/R4wQ/jFrstcbzuEBmw/V4PpixbFlxEdYKh93Yjo/O@8PRg0@97JQsEWFNyoBPtRj202Pc0bLMkucTY5fKSV6LohrW52QY@CmpBFXHx5QdarqOiCDBKP/I10CMekv0dnm15nAAp2az518EzSZPXyb4tp7F0DXmRNz5e@5B8TIacpBpiT52ncmwJw@1va8@vK4dqaPXdbXzbuuv6uP@O/WhtncEFw5v323uNrYU/V/fO6yrjG1iqhCpEQtKout20AoQf1etlEpPFEPe6g/GInfyW458P/Qv1Ot@K8Ax1YvIv3h5Li9eLxhtSKk6LUfH2MMMOTLnRTiCvQWHkqRlLJSbNt/MxE0LRXlPaU17gTXvRb8ddkLKm8HadxAGkbnMp7oh9SDJW3Of3RUlCVEj2XSIo8HCAuuaivuUH2c3BMYX@yuQGDkkzGTbU5pw8b/vpuBR/eDNoYI3kK39ve3GUWN/71Dt7B/Q69uPjb1XRM/G4dFBY/Mdkjjjm/3txk5jq8YfBIGSp@Cm45fLaDQXBQ/ZmSqtzzj59gbU/fFbetcbGry69vmOaqSWLnuQPqHfDX8L2kvrmcsI6gvuxfJRgcov1g5evac5XwW/4oTTHAWz/UH2XcSRTBdL6gXXRoNlg8bbuh6uNO0Vyg6fR1yMFYIZBevsviPPz64ywNmIpx0GKrsFGxXsfYuXDx7LBjRV9IBgA5QxWKkqDkK2tOS@YJAbVFur24dTVqlNjAj1C4q@NKYm6xmmmLaVAVDcJWn0sB9UXo8/EN/ThxVd7WgoGdTj@INkUE/kA1TRBmxH1KrOcTnav4R4Vmvy4ZeLwQ4fC6un8YdNn1exzzRO0m/cpb6KgzjC50mXQ83JLg@Hw/WjVhhykYjzIwxbtysDI5AAoCQT5SiRbdsoZ5aETQdHDdrsTQJrI5W4AXZCfmcUqXzV8dQRjIOCXihB/s66fk9MoBLTHeY99QwOpqr6CnwYB8fj2zmDPjMgAnOm8YjLbWutMLhvOSq5OVWjr20kOUCtMUG7C4HNKQT@CBgCVEitdFo8U/G1YYDpdzQr56M@cST2bX@38xM7ty9bQaqAttrK/xL@9pujieym1knGTpGxoy76LRiSWslHmZ3@kMY4i1UOJwYp2DrvD0ah9GE@3QI@ceJpjnJjYqPafq5upGoDHSZr7PV7VqWnxMW31HpKTHmfWpnj5ew8Fl9JnGnifJqExe4O6Pin/avAOjtzcYh0HWD7hRRhPivH5ud4xJiI/plJZMfvCuFpn1U3tjc/FX7/2UWMWhELEiLaGB3if2JM1EXDg8/52GBxCL1LjzQTWzC6PEVpbYOnpSVGuQFG68DzkNZ1L5vrcZqYG09/x82lye/88evXqpQqQDLpuOLReT6Rbq46NlW6XOZEaRMQS3YSsiTr8@aLyzBjef0St5XQC/CX1IMcwbp9InKfFiGmdaeXHZIsOoCy7u4YvqM22KIiiT6PW0h2fxR/ym9WlzecYmJQoixy5o2Idg3ksuNYZik8X02B254PjuT3/cE9m4udTA/fBW17LrTvwq2wfDssmZYsWPcH@/scsDK5/SGw1Hb3dsAySU5Dizk9Zk53MRdb086v8eepvuOxR2Aw92IHJQZq1XbZ4yNq4@I8LwUcG0yiEB0ebdcPDlRW1idUluQelgxtLQYB@4F6m1jbhj0Wdl6sNMWL5Vh5Ml9SFm3m37zBPJN4t4gKrYO4mh6xsEgcqXfCG5F6emZhFYKt71kgGsqlsftiZFB0rAF/ozUgIZt0mtXAzMxm5mTyCSPbCFzTzRXd2LbhZwtrmbsRlng4tgHZNkH@GW6WzO6/D6IfV0w9omDByRQa3CZNmuYbWiccUsUDyuh56R6c0y2mS2FkLwp2ztAOhl@ltIb95xmKGUmUcNGFLbGulWONmujHi0bNYYNETAM@LD11olg0U4IR8fzlhd2hTjLp5dNTECmZCFT70uYKKn7yTU9hTI14nqzGCrk91hYZm2OD5Ql2ZzXs9dszPYQt9NqkeJisiqTt3KoK/5iqZJZI1WRoPrMxJpEgr62uPr4L9mQrTPHCn4Utc8ik/BxdDGh9n4CMxhFv7xPnNvZck54wwBzSiWm9GTATBUnVmTGnpNrOk5GNH@Ei@0KEDOICIPbvZK2OupnAbTZ0mZFs6Jxlqg3WEI4bKqNmivrf5lcHgXxnfQ@@vz4ZbMgE08FvsMp/0x9GQXIrz3KfY32C24H0t2A47HE2uc90ASh5vsY097Id37YTg1dpFRL5vM1uSUffThKzW9fsNXAlvL3oIdw3dvfWJ7f3CuV1u6k7jd26esReQjupvcjsMOtYsudB2JuHAMtg3pfA9MF3@B5GFfqfcHANSCIT3@bLM22cO3FjipDWfMyBo7RZqJat5cne70QtvweHK272YaSy7g9UkHdh6/s7zqyd9dJ6qjwhFw16eSrlZgtelovSN2zoAlIahPQmvlsTFm5qGEtJXK8568M@CgdbwY3snrHlpF8sPyutPc9w63ruyL04fn7iPmpVs4omX793EV0Or9ufz/rnVx3VVYNfTm9a499@VWr1iXpMda38IM6ay2vVInvHfUp/n6nnJeZcjeCPfF8e4ac9icur1JJK1uHrD5TDD7xoruCGxASXqkcXhgtxxW5UvTheO6n2qqX1i@PeyTou@Y2Wq6Pl8nIeH36gWZRkjJzMH49OMKfau65B70rBISrHf9VXQxRfDaEvb/xh2N@t7b1K7cZBAcAWmLb15g11CfW9AGs23D3xesF1Xm@TuQocm4GClFngW0Fl@AXg/WRsx7RDwox6xSVtNrrhv2Mns1DyLgejPqcY95dgLfU1/JpZMNeYSryjQFmOQ@MkE/cLCE6SJ4@DIfk6FivqQlnUtTLuTjoWiGOUZHGY/ZTN4k4hENV3uY5PMpEX@K1zIIHY9l@5mHrxgiPdE6tFHu/iwZTDH/KFidIJHnEAQj8DPm1AFay5R3ztI0PNx3sZD/KF96hGfE@GDeQzrCkiBebf6gvfb@LyL4gAQvgF0bk8vcWpNS9SJOXuIG8uwLdceuGPYwZcq5ROWUBjAVvqqybA2VKcaYRqNZno@8I1yCm0on@6BYUyv001I87vSHYmCZ9T67cItOQu5aQN/HSTYnmrWMEUM5ktUizcSQ3sdNHy6E1Aw2qstoJul5AWWiwk5MAj3@/V9S/H9UfHqPMkRl7SC1PphVS6J@mCVJLLowk@yVSxM2VzX5J831Q2yeZO1VVVrLx41NMtj1SSJO/6vLyRN@o3wyTzRtyVwpVxwotUQsFK@WlG70vKg1SZmMHj9GNJ1/y9ons@xjKV92W6fvxmdAcFbDyrbU0muNTrhd0fMzosuk4Bm2WJmkpJcQ53qcygquo7mFqckAaHfX4ethvVBMpy2UgcHjPZjRcvs55WMn7MT6IhtxinBtaMMWJRietcZsLd8IVFqoeTH1ggGCYYTZmRu2EKj3XhsQUWuR6YauUW5NQAp6ZNDvEq7kV@xR8z2NPImXy52YkLgvmNNF5uN6cJxEL3QXY2mdLSBNdF5KNu1JxZJKl7PAlxtpDYs3aB4zoDuYPdwTb4g1hO2ILCSIopuscpmtJJhrJh39u6EInfMn8vPsq88knHHnSDG1XDMsPnW1iZ1AX3URCNIrjcYm9A0eVg0MWpIyt813yFWscfWFnFcUsC0ZrZvUwDlj2S38WTvpBOhTy1D8jXMBBJEqLLszNcJsMN2P41RCt2XMKRl6n1xrKhQWPm8YpcMw8UnG@wAO6GZzYS0nMyekDpaOC3Ai9DOlpE2k9GmtoJdZRY3k/HvRF4dqMprZLJ/Mtl2Pq89QrnuU/Lpcdli2RX@ji45D1@klywIiKZhBU4Z1wtP8lkrLPhlpwNFwDQVbuY6N8TbwZXQa8XZGo0Y3DGiJTWKBheBW0vkzkI4kNgwAUr42QS97D7l8OWbO6Q0uUTM@KWcOTKcRhxGH4xP8txcYvPytwMDq2S02bq6quwDQKaGyedPk6H@cACbgKEHih0EYyIKI8clUaJz541Lqy7XGAjiqgBPyfW2URMhl5/FLaoZ3gnK9MlUHIMklTWa09gQvW1uj4uB3uzEMD1mIQCBgFzlDQPh4w@NP8uHJRumDlj903PFEn69Xms0HAPhiFJ34TA3CtczMKdOvjodeNQHe7vHH2oHdQVPb892H/f2K5vq82PfMaNg3J2fKxe7@@SdIlP0@XUfJ8@ZGuHVDLLCZna3kdV/9vbg/rhodo/UI03b3cbBI3AH9T2jhr1Q1c19rZ2323z6TtBUHv7R2q38aZxRNmO9l2u1RTLJOXU/o56Uz/Yek2vtc3GbuPoI9e40zjaQ2U41a@pt7WDo8bWu93agXr77uDt/mFdoWGZ7cbh1m6t8aa@7VH9VKeqv6/vHanD17Xd3YmG7n/Yqx8oNhKwWrlZJyxrm7SERU3czu3GQX3rCA1KnraIeITgrqsO39a3Gnio/61OzakdfHQ10MP6v7yjTJSotmtvaq@ocZn8HVShftl6d1CHByVQ4vDd5uFR4@jdUV292t/fZlof1g/eN7bqh@sqs7t/yAR7d1h3FWJYctUEg6hF6fS8@e6wwXRr7B3RnPHuLewdHOrkD0QYwrJGRbeZwDCDQGuJSPsHHwEVdOAOcNWH13X6fgCaMrVqoAIsKraO7GxUIRHxyG6m2qu/2m28qu9t1ZG8DzAfGod1hzqscYgMDRhkfCTWoUrfcavRT4SXPBKzZgznutydqrGjatvvG8Bc5yYOOGxobmGybb3WNPfgBtnaRAn72DPwL@yNlc70p6sAjj@nd2Rm79HEHpO29rfrNCNrZ1fZJOEdzTrPJlwp2Wk008SJ9JpyWdMOTi/PmmGv08cd07iYbHxcRGcuIjM5CGrzKTMnQJneX@ECuVyz@b7WpIXuYbPpuPcpmULjrhJ6G3xeLke3EUEvsPLGxk@lInR/kSLUxg/6oJMN9XAAgZxC/R/E9M2/CBxVLLYDXQyX9wHYbB1FcmxyjqMUEo182RHReJIqeWeC30PNDlwwb8B7rSb2SWEZyZn6Ef3pfU1eZHKwPpB0lu2uYhGLWEYj/C0w1Ugl7BKB/2iPBGGHq/SiIPh8li/Z1WHN7531@@2845gynHdE68CzvHNH8dPgbKJ4YbI8I8vHzjpeRGTW3azCxOfPmmRK94s35Jbl8ac54h/HYCM@H7BrylXxZrXetMz/IMVhkeQq7doC1yu4k6Hzvan9rfEBq7nSypP1ie@v4@8ytmAvCBfBNOEdc7kT/nl9IhlogLEvDiJJqD1kFItWGWNvEme@poznyHQdtmH5Q3P1ecDzOpGEFNlLv2vXidl4GN7Y2JMcfnVQe7P5bmeHRCewffJs9enaeiZ2u/U3V34/oh724stexwY0j5OexknWKNkixYdHiuVEPWF/ZuBiERnhMN90Gn@En4fYbiNtyQRBhuZGCE3Vg4leNgAdsoodcDzIGH6dOTI1A@RTTXXQmgv/hlV8n3Ql5gFtzNIdc6/d4A9gx8PfDPG4QZqBNIuxX2PiXFpdsNzL7hhTUV7csOMeZPGyho/FjVtMA97qYvtZ3K7lN83bVi9GYsqI8crdziUJiQeTWChjV9GTkf2W/YzoDWD2HkZf/qb5jR4/agd37O7Oj0a10SGRcScuiX3qZDNaN/pYQz5BABM4VTM1vVDY5Xc0Ujz29HZy7BjEGg2MCqLxwMY3DXg99iMyWSVbwL5cctQX4VQ47wCcdc2x@p04d1ZzNJR14z9EvxuvFEpgxU5OhGrXcR0Zk@Vj7MfCkDNFpj9FD4b/T6TJDPgvaMVJ0BNqWU4A70VJhiq0ouUrEyW8NgcN1ulGQk3708cEzDe7Y87jhunTmxu5X0Mk0L0zNh8@stvDTn4GAcDk2Niwx29sknbu09LpZdbRxXFO0mtdDPJKzxVmqpiCW1g7cVntcs3ZCl4c5chek1XhLhVVL2XhdsqjnpZME0t59TDKCjjH@P8oPuINkHjAM5eei9XqJGeV9CgzckC7WrImnHbsMYnU0m@3nto9UpaLzJTs1ydfhlAEegP4TLeTI7n0lZjnpj0u8kysjtgLHny1Y5mMyUe7rDtlQ8xuADgP27wZgmAvo2tMEF2Bzq76Emgq/5ANRVBJYnWY@BmEuHU8Ii1Pq9cx9rwzCQ6NsX/XkzABgexqmRyeOPjQGNrX5T31xh8Tyt37NVtYrPjosO/CdhGVybaELo/ANq1@f0iqo492E45uOHY89UFvOgS96HKo/RfSfBYO9Y6EUfqpGqhNsnrnaUb88zNqUTjCbYW2x/zBTboIYCEq7kluCmsqT8xreHTDbDqGN8tllX@RpLwgmrBbUibiC7Wmvn6VXEJQ7TI0YAqGUby4YJtNrgfnDvHwu@4PP2PuhwrUawft2DOpBZL3AqWTGj328dgaSdMH/Yh3NKgrsAMSU6IsG2mxoSrN0U81O2m7pmziHRO@S7kl319PzKTGWooqShhX107Mt1agzgSVVrRr0NhZaHlllVGZteD6dutijL2Fpo@tVfZTLxYpFVEiqg@N6ognkZvx00c86U3@6sMIo4e@4Ixbq6BAGDorzlWn5RzjB5uCD2EwbNt7oqTJtP0Btt946dPvMS@arUPt9q/lj6JgTCuAVjG8KTKMZv4v/fNec6vf9c/CfujTOg3O9W9E4uFxzI/osLNh/zrimE2c0LYytcfJs/iXETdseI/PJdct11zRKBjkbTOF0XBcOxc3EbxzDiPAJF4s8/dg0kdaXObJalIok75/yvZ4ZWf91rKPy7MKy4k@AGgBtzFhQSF3SEd8Mcm6fLo@leF0XgYLx1NVUL5zi8VeCuPnRCI@hklhbJCZMkuwG4GV2a0YH7dv3Db7IBzC0VKwHSDaUJTnz66PINwkRX6EpUBFlZ@VrKJyinIDP4R4GN9O7pWn/2TsCYE/gX758SxumcUILOI6xttSJOsV7WWUcGHzwJBlNEtikmLhWdizrh9yaI@bSajp5PFt1GDLH1KKtJu9Ka7EiMzTwgehBfNNEjnNsYNJZUktOey3AypIbZQv3c6wwV32szz4cYgrO2cQTFsact5C@jZStYhKCHI8YV5royw@le8eMSsr9@21CQJWZ5mcWeG281mjufANlFDmVxxr9YckjLMT1NOmHkvRqD9Yuif1bpUdMz2zzaJ1y3HuNAQWZqvSZPmozaStjvE4Xs9M4jPBNGmKsaUZ8RCWr/wcs/kkEW@qTYy3anN8Bx1uo1liNxVPKnF/t2XsY1K8gkWvmWjiIcW4w0npevz9uEkNb94uQTRMWV41WWI0ITKaY3m0QE2QKabS/SnE3Kdxn6BHmyiHettEO7t/biXqpJGccXlqklJOLkFPOG7HpU2SS4MOjC/gJk403FhIxQrnjTvmo7xy4RROhpEgAKEVB4VkH0p2cJPOmuAjjg7QyTdhLVSGJKKnDdvCIXb6HxOMvfLrzR1t8dAcF8on6wLpJoZEqwrONQ@SuW9Or8fNG4YyRQoa4jNIEbdoSjad379Vf7YtlI8gSGlO1pa@JReNcdQyYUN/7KTmDXTgpCpdMjWi0gOhyaKBxgKtUs66gSxXof2FQ@F4WDfoYUQLCPmcx8@yLgF33mulmNooctMeI4ujyS2jzVGFDSmSMJS8g/x6KIqqywtXAhAIxlS@WiYIcGvK2ONQgF3v2JyXQlT3ERWsljEs6SN7RU3sPGekg6g6w5NVK0dpVo7nNozCTCCkWMzOkyBCOsvsLAkUmuhm4mLleDq7PUkOUogN7wvFqSt0r6RpGPecEJCje5ecRKIcl5Vb0hzMiU9WnVRizN@c@rxkpZYmU4k@MYbHhfJk6rNSKjVV7cpKumiqJNHDsWtNJRIpHBvhWCr8uX98NcV2eR7bhFqLjJSWoe2zEX2dVpm0bvN@idQLvpRtdAwDz74ZbpZfTQmxknLKPt8Bu1riIwP4bv/TrTWWqQYTHSuA/dKZyy55WRCyxprFVI9mYaVrPO3FDgrMmrbfUe@PdnZSbl9Px8bQ6CIYrpZKJTDxqe383thWYysp7BfTuYudy263OLj@y/D9aZFlfxBwSICKWUEH1CU0KCKvPzyTyBDAgbIid0FfZMVa/7LTsUMw4IQSnUfdJjm1NwTFE1AYG728P@INIAapJ9if0UC072cVj75rXxRNDcUcQ1FpmARfZc3pGZEHHzqwz45PqhgYBLOxZqJ5y6lufMEMgsgm3Fnsvtj5kpgnZ18H3W7fVR8Q9RmeAha@TRbY2bELlCQLThj5du9lxP5oXRVchV3rXjGy2LwOcGZiMnEmjF94@MY/CM7qN4N89vinLE0r1ORlNHMZ/qldlT3LOtpZ/D3ACh8S2vfKfeEP8i2m02Rmmur1CE6eCKPHZXfm2ieVxeE9MU2zu3ODqLPR9dhZAzXdYV3A@LLn7uWW3JI9Jm720025AxqWBIbGCT5X7lcCV83@eWLxatTp3E8qchgA6djvkogSCeXPCUQ@A@ARqIcf0RNetP9aoGG9M@FQRBQcBOuYljso0ESBTOZhq/rrdb5Wq6nFwfKyqtU26aFQULXNmtrGh81NtU3vm3j/obqyurouMnfb@UIfN83Hb2qTYPAO53LrfLhNr5RWxb0xWGujixeL1UV3fbFZfbGxHhWPa5u41k9P//lv//U///2/FWv65X/gZZNfjn@KM3meV1xsfVn84ds63o@3T5YWT48XBydLZ@vgsr@z1/B@Y1TwE/NRb3iaycksYH1lO1KzzmbvM7qoMvEDL/zhZ5IuFZVrRcWc/hpJ5CiWsblWYH0PcI/ylJbwJujA5FKekMgR0DG246l3WgEM8Gi@IUoSLrADlfJytmI27uEOJs4Qn6rktCce1lmvAtxpSTwp4C4uzViFsBcFPeyAX7HOK83LZHz6DUdNzb/Fn95EZ5v9G/XoU149KqlHrnqUzfJPee05fXUWiyFu50o2Wg5ksy6lJEcLMDNUUciKHq8fONbOBLkzmUUO2QNIxk0FZ5ZbcG68@uPLMhJwLTrLLCDAqZItEj5kQpHcl8XeN@qWL5TjWzZ11YYVhaZexXBl1olK3L9QgfxIDAGSmi@EIJU@VYmTPr6RjKei@aL7OsPRhBgwyHrwaofHPT7QXLTY0zbPqbUUwhyx@bx8xdy4LpehGW2kSP0JAnygIsvJEt8kXMotZcTK22olN1NuYdvt08wntg7jYGRs06XQ78piArHmtgm32NP3WrQhtxyvqGwYH69YVWUnbb9VxipycdkdhQN9XYFrx4D6Etf2TUYSepQBCRzx2V@ZHmG8UWA8RU10iwTLGqt2H02XkdDTV9Opgx1PTo4sIhR/ytPY/joxtp0i3xIx7CA8wEjFpnwdP@xG2uvKkIl95g9PER3Q73BAtZGcm/F@HgLVTmDc78RIewyZTc6T8UxNyQ2G/tmF76rcXv9o6I8bNG2R5jNqeQ61EC6YgAQGn656VvMMwtIi3SVMkbgpbDmE4AXdsQ6PJn2bje@coEvNUNBuVzAIUuzElAy@pvpqgo4JV39HJ9goTwnv@DRSi1iWvLA00pCy9rUZHmZTQydjarDHTjxwshlBNR6Zhhd0oUtMtBd88EuSvAsfAbrurL4FqK8irD1H/ZidzoKen5qcBt2MuehfXFcyL2I8cyhKsUbKaChPy0nEO2BFeuRPaS8QMjcZd0aZhXx@4VOkw7nl7HmEnXzHtvhFX4VxADoOYMY3Q9S7XijCcmKGSmJgeKrBlv8EodP1zwi/8bU/Bit@yuV/fFB0jn/61Dt5lP/U@/rpN4cx0SLZzLIFldOH2UZi6bFCM2PRTb0aq7TIuBr81Etn@NRTcofFIgEhUswf/1Q8@VokhD7lHOdR8VNOCJLqMmBSnF9fEeCLU2jm0lgUc5kF55FjOj//Y9lRNLfyL/pQPjjyS1iYRSVv09M6Z9ghUHxP99dLuXISFZ@tlJ6slJ/QSugsuCkMg0vMt4Xo8jS4IVUiwnKWpp5Pv6W4IUWIbzeRv04fb6idEtZE7p5E@pKSFqF6mHM9mZitqIwnPEH5icrsLhVXXJw4j4/DRyz4XUUsZ/KyLygxHbS4L4/5M@pfoB4/glybvB0iHAkrA7ER4S3UAiCb4Cu3cahjhssS33Py1BZ8tzIQ6t5izpotev1eQStrjre0DiUat2a6z0rPSpNjdGqIpkboolamlh6o8saPT//jv@//mhvlNlaKH4b0O8r9mlt7lpNHeqC3x@btKreRe4Fsa99y4yKtgenx6X/8Tyq/8ReCg5TxC/qzsWpgrY1zG4UqF/ma21ijh/LKCtX7v/71X6kNi7JiQyzWxaarGLF1Q5Etv8e8S@mqgVbKsnQpESt8MQswxMKQ1ub0AsOom5VnJd6my2mriqtAe74y9ih6imfDrBGbCslOhrGnIM1IClRRQUFAGhOKjrJsN4zZBpg3QVP9/NBbi2gF8LM254irjE03HkYwGVqUZRF1YF5qpPW8PGyUfszG5h2VrLEpWTcqJJZ2WtY@e7xO7PC2H4zCVtpKwgzXi5Z/HZx64EMvaF/SmqoXdfu/DItXxJIX5ZVnxQ4294tsx10cMKTCYOz9RoqgDgZEC0M2OnXVkHqgfwEXXi5HCyKFfic@kzLxJEnLHgQt2cNKxySmLHLHz5XjYTTHS1TpPP8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qceldw/qKjscpxR8vGa1wE2b9k4VrvAKIg17IBlk5fhNmB30LTHqw3P@BISl4LXdcni@e1209dp@cxC1oRKczML50F3UM12xL07fKfixETTX9TMW6EUQuwgFAos6ADrIhj5tESvZvkL1uNJDXCTos9aY1dxCVk7Oq9e1berHHVlTtXXUvU19Si0hKSemGcsb2zKziaypYqtymHQxJHazIqptsgEbR56/AMMIumWRgfXEnRz@AYkUS1pjrYqs7vN5bUw8ch1IHf2ZGtRIldncsnlR9fkkBvU0J1QryeVkYCAF9wKLJTp/VBuQFRNmNGwlxF/fhPJxr@HBsNt2IcrUdttnTgflWmpd4XYN@GI71IqIoH2K2vbYGdk9ohBxy624hC0WWy8ZB2wVKfCiy3OaLqjwmGgjUuobFb2qY5bKg4v29HRayVQBH3Ilsorj5@srj199hxRzhZ0a2eDQSEPq4DBuU8wWKPO0yIb36vV7FJWPiEE9XSVgD4LLA7gYNZ17TjG7fO186BaLmlgpSzDuuYwGlJcb1cyyATiMPAwI9AaJT/M5vM/Vo7RsJNPbecr/U/8bfwDMsMZd7S@kN7qh7eJZ6rMhTgcqLJgZqc4@cfwoOLoFDtv0O8cwNtEAFtXYXuqaBceIEbnw/7l2bnNHZ52bXVEA4YIzn6psYJ6FYwSB2MWVtBF9YZDw7p9UTXwjqdbAKNcTAnQ@QQ4DTPtt9LXlqYYHUs0CcGzJm6s4gjRMh212Zm5s9dX9b3tScRydhg6huvZlq2k3LEnMziQQaxeq7lHRF3t7YKvkmqZ5Ka8KrOAKyFfma/D@7gr3UIgaosqRlaz3jDKzyNLmXkxcW2aFKV@BF4zYJZLd5PS3Gs1rQBBjCDUu0mxEHPj8xybZAlOdidjnIKXsxXLRvRNGEXsYE5XlnW0RSln4qgCC5lbAGLfppSVhpQq6FF@rHPgZeltBHOUW9HYGtBmyPFKNZiZk8NMsNVtJA6wEXXc0ALtb@xtuWq7Tn92Pmy7UJQ3a39Fu@MQz7fjW9b4liuqsWO6wPYWyza3sJn6FVeUiFlK2mFsgiCEb0eiIgaJ14B6Y0fTXgb1cWpsnyRcAXb1tRJudkf1IIGjF94DWdCL99gVB1/X4W8V2byaljSxSxU9LGSLa/7AtmiykNQaQxJS3gPEyiSI2FFLwu0LCcOLBTpr3r5euxjGbuzM5ukUy8qCitT2nSKRPc2zt1JmHlusaLZYqaAf5/EF8@1c3jgNOn19Fy1mjjt448Ef443C/Zmj8P8Fc9T/OdzxWHPH4wpkj3BH7Dacb3RyGPb@DI45HfMc3GyHZyH2hzrWKxpRci0ALPCAIe6QUmK5hLbdIk5UfnbC8uR8BCOhlVVcDPhDjX@iG/@kApnLj9vB/6uNL/yDG7@qG79awVwzo@e1ame5W//HtDhRCfPpDzO7F@quZHP@aEvXdEvXKphNZ3Tz//WWFv4PtfSpbunTCjwmyIGDuK@fz82iidQOtxqNxNzCy2inXXnEsZ/NlQ7WXu1qlhYPne5ldF6Ftq7@MP7PNP7PII34CWHocBYR24bGa3lZnspledEseZdD4ZKVtETaazyjW@3VE1ayHtETlAhp3tga6oUKKeSuJCanTV6iPybSN5587ouzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZScZ4qL56iCZK2vxvLLNPpDV1tHB7vJ/ETJc@J/1LTRCHl17HXS7Ziaxl2BHsdcp3RirOYB9qNccKVbR5GRkR/q2d8wuC7dLNXZsMTEvzl4kyFEbzv9oLXUBfcOKyo0tI6KNp8ubVRVMc83yQr5Q2yXT7CbrFv8hLn2uufR5RR3ohcFtpPL1hp/mxWSdtrK6Om8OkFIefjAASy7lnzOq/jc)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/xjfvd)

Noulith has `#` line comments and `#(..)` block comments. Parens inside a block comment must be balanced.

`( )` on line 613 is for RETURN.

Answer (score 1):

## 380. [Erg](https://github.com/erg-lang/erg), 16500 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>8053在ｕg=1\0C0-<?MLot ~7+<p>3:s4o 8let d=   5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpKRSqW7pdlWpukp17/UlWSyQBEmUQIAFkBJZkiq6e3Z73bZn1tPTnmi3Pb7tnvVsez0R453YWbd37JkIez9OOOaTf0D5sbHh2HD/g95zTgIgKJFSVXscMbELiUAiHydPnsw8eU4@Djq6N/zZz2J4sSeONR9YzoRNDG/Ceq55argyuztnu7rp5bWsIGCsPXcwHRn2xKsIMaYyZun2YKoPDNY3rYnhpplnGKxjWM4ZhGuMbU/tqWf06vCWZcw2ztih3TV7AIFNnBPDNt8YLoTlGLtnWBejiwnrOqORbvc8NnZNe0Khecae6PDSn3ZPmN7xJq7enZiODUEFxp7blj7q9HRG0ceuwRMVGYDqnlCa5ZASY48c1zMgB6dreJ6DnmXw1F3Tebj3@OMr8dUM@1gHpMaWMbuSvaqyz0zD7V1NobFPj@/fv@qbZV@THJvdv46SmmN704lzOLkKP8/2BoatM00uy9rVwAIQc2JYpUwpczWoCPVpTMzuUj4QcN90oXZ1vxZZV7ehtrAut5gxGk/mTOL1r1tWWLce0z029aa6RfHs6ahjuEFEb6K7E9MesDNzMmSToemF6Si2N9a7htQzLHNkTowes0xI5PR9KADa7rETY37muFDlPkzHtuaQ0OiafROTBHgAQLwSk6HB4Yz0OVSyPYHGwXTmARqWEUBLCjGIf8/oTAfMmU7G0wkD3Hqmp3csANqZs57R16fWJM06EAZEJv@zoWH7jRnAyQDi2OFYvZoSasaizeu9HstAOwY8TgxmAtUIrQrLZsGfOS5QDWIFGPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBsIPQh/EVrc8x0dmGTUMtKGvUp0h3CeuM3D1EVCjZxBNPz18wryu48Ib/DAu7083genqE7a9zeIHj@/FWT2sFtntCGEV1dg5VEEsCGSnujWFFhKtCQfqxw1TC1hl8Y14hcWBLFqG5XIsB922xLQ8EEnNlMEB/V/LqvArMK3Ecir0oHw8jfn0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5pcM/kWFYt8ZgDx@rzaF3KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFeZmUNckPQOaaW8/ArwA@glQEVFX7ZHAe0aPfQTrGt7bO@PjKtuQ@dwHdZXmVFgAj4qgBZKwEEeGaz@MvCj9BavqKwJ0Og9lA/BfCSZZ4gNzJChoRVqMBD2dpSiCMiy@XZe0PMHkgHRMuXWBGyLwAlcoACUFYrQfb5DC@INzQsy0829DAZYVvMwA8wLwIdSkD9DNAyg8Qswg/egd9pwNg04GIaMCYNmImmgTuLWUC8AoQVoCoLPr2GuncCGfF8tB4RHzg6gFGR2sjEVCQSQIDaYlmoswLLQUPIYkPIZxngD7gUCwz4WEllpRwrFRnQs5xhUDcq4IWtRAX@qQI@KgKD@lehAaiAkwrUVgGoms0zIUJsNYvhkDYLaYE0ag7S5MANFacW8AfpoGWokKUKeWpaedEIATctD@XNZ6l1agWo3SKEAd00wFWD5qQBtloJwjFtCWhYwsZbjKc5IXSkA9QKNndoh0CMPOBDcCEuuLViltNPt8ZDvYPcmqfs9DFpAbtBAckISTNYPHjmkJqASgbAYC8A9DVoAVkgRxaqNpsLs7dUANJA8EbPJAZtmcC71JBCxTQ1yFf6eLIgm1ogjMbzyTD007ifA4zTBOZnDPTuPAyE3pcOAxe@hSz6asRrF4AyOfT1gLM6U89aAAkdOY2yMk5Na@FXIr@eoff6pjd8u8A1R5l0DH1imyeLXPL5dISoeiSggAFLXsVsNO7ElGC4GgzRtSiLVsQ4YyesoCWUVZXQ6xj9qT0wpHIpgh@FTKbuBAaWRZ5l7u2agwGMyQs4apqKSQPlwjtPGFrZ7EQIPZG6mKdrwvB9h3WHIFCEgWUOv1xewMhqCGOud3BUl0AKg1GgjONW35yxzp0ujRoLBLNEp@7QHAeRK2sjRyqXMpmVCpG2QZR7U8qErBmvlvzKMe1EnMWTwqUAYw2XLKMjNQxon@EoheMuNl0YVx2SGhbsM2EHI2MSiLY8yMOoawEbhUrp6jgC43hk0HgawDEnMoNMQAw0nFMUW2lQXMrGo4Gz46KUClJOz3BdhnFBtPXSNMR6045nvJ6iHLXAqw9jtgFDe183rRABGkf0CQkA8Ix7kN98Ge2@64xosBnhEGo5zniNuAID9hkCeuCcGQvUF@O5Ph5bIDWBv8GFNkDmTCd5m4TzaK4cIUiE6aDCASBlBdKG6Rpdor1fdEidBblkGcUK0@p3sgjlbkScykJnAVHDwzT21LIqIOcYXZatKz3jVEEfLnIti1qIQyCEgSjlg@joICsj5oRFCOmOJpN4dxzUrOeMlovGx9fDsOhDEwUj60yfQ@31YWg1ZvoIJHqGYjP0XDaCFsNrEGsCdBYs1iHrOXZ8EkI5c0GIhUKHJSFBGWkyMUcGaD8OJMEazxHSOLoTZp05NGWiVk4mdYdjcoVQsnCVUNwjF/HgnQXEvd60i1TDvE2bWhCISR7K@C6wSu4nTFzWbOrwc0GeG/sanowOjPgMUYsoCB7v7b7k3SWIKKMatgdqhSczE/UvaPkDpw@N7cyEsgPDgqQL2F0iApIg9JrJXVkgkmMDGp1YzGTd8ZiBPwxK0DzvZ0oggjqvTPYGAq0hqBDdqevO2WwMNWGOINak6/T70HrfGOMhgGCjHuvOu9A9oZKx9Qg9hxhMd7xczMXbpgFxbFRK9p/8IhsYQHYQWPuonWKTXxRgPKYiECl0mwuztg6UwiJ0x3MiixBbpOg7joz@PcfwqLE47knY9TEzzxhQ14B@1l8woxEK59BKbVIqesB5/O6F8DFDYWVhMCu/FXxs2NB1utAqodND9WGd7rE@KNkRERb1DL3bNcYTv504xM5MOyLvH91HeZ98JR@Y7A2FzV22faXVQNSw5URkWdR/EPWxr4boyGt9TV4iwSNUOTlnsebXsocYp1dyF19inCUMXoprcBhTl0Dlh5jEdIKsBLmj2R0iL5wgtyF5G3qbO71efPCLZu@OmNQP80ZsVGA7gqyEXojHehgS/KzrgOSxhbDqSx4YdcnjFtC6N1oB2QmRtHpRX1nRZWCKtwEdObazAioQM4SLUZZDqC6oMT5DrqFbYWOk7uIt1REy7MXkEg5kMIaOx44LPYMznTnNJFCVRVqXr4AnwrEiKbO7y0MrDBlxHPAnOApCgrGlQ1vALoY9FTQrHTgFMDGuIAPPc3iOEYSp1xMsH78zYv28McFYatsGKme6O@dAoHgwPENGc2a6LrDBUxwk@BgUDCYytVMYE/ReDzkrkoP6/dXMZWzR@9OOObuqhXfRU37lCae6y/qogLsgdEAnSsT7XjxZJX9KGQkSFWc8USgpv4sQkSLJUOWJPuj0MEjcB0bzbG53E@JSFxPTTJxO@iUxCQ5MyGU09gmoClexQ/UBG83oBPo1vVXZAIZvSYK7hH6ECQYoMgboLsgZ0AlByyyXex2dXQD3cJk02@eqSKCSqHIuzMuwe2FePiEQl2h5ZZ6F53bJIUVGNSwBRqeS0yCxRMD3pAQlFMFDUfyxFT1I2uNhJNdwz6lN83AswUWRJDsPhV8YABKEjAnCh9k1J21fXLlzJxBcNmo1aGwgTQHb7CWjGm0wYSkDp4bIMkkjfibyxHk2wb6RSEJ5MfIlxwbEJmiptTo7nwxd6HH0filAJCCrYGNLDgjr1/Nj82Tau1rRNnpiJBF7HQhNZnciVgUY/HlvqN1E1fgSVUHrjSNVsfFiegJ9rfGSL1ao6EdzDQ/F35qPSqSGE4iB31ZXkogn9f0WDXp/3rV8kYC7oLNzbtQB9E/8iayQEaV9mSDotNd6KgeC3YHDYU/2jh/U/L7IA5WOaVeWPCynq1vkvYnRxSDtw8O7T/ee/mJ7BQzL7FSueihmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@F77ZtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8@jp166SBCQhJAflAG78XRFpeBwQuoSO7g2vDMJskEpBlmGSIC6TDlkAM3Qg6hiuB/g8mb55g5V3Famx74@YWVOdAwg8lUM7SCdj4BUBLAjq9PmISGlBCjVtXGhYuKIxA3w@Rqn5KjIkSkeazMdH9w@e1gisP68mURTFm4Aspbs9Gdq8NQUVfFUcYH/g6rKUvEAc5WnCdSWBu90lAi/qlq2BDwBQ15EdJlmjoGjeEHDfv1o28pW6YQugd4JwVa6MykPdD0U0ggcOcV1UeVeNohSwGKxCr5UjVhi6PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs9eFCgtCsA4EMiNLgSdeBL6yAsp0herffSfPbyGuEdCJKgCUoCZZzGZ8vIsAbUXyWRxT9kHDc2xDPkz4ngiE5OKEg/WBeSuR8pnJP7BzJwkMkn@VJMQF3Lf2zvU7gWR/SlrmskgpQF1cRyZ3D6u73U9aCO2YzkDh21BGi4dBhmC2LS2mHsDx75WQzp6YlFjuEQI/BcnbvQxjDXmG1IcKVVUXeWLjbrtnQGXVgtZJBJRiEApFF9@pZ/qQK5FuZ8dfnEAg4iaz2RCd4YuIEEkDZELXd2IL3kwCTKSfXxWFjBcLrzW24MAKbJeh4X2GV2YcG8RvNKTOKasrIy/EqVPnGsUf@XMrzQt8OFNCxwRkh0@fvLw8PHBo73PmxMtn196z2XKBSAc5NcBWUgecrphb93iXROLheBi0Ddc7F7ABaagoASrRVPPBcYtYxSZI7Cm1fCF1sQnztCOe8mrhTnDUOmV3eVN6BF2Ph7VTwiKds9CZcTlq9U4nmP7GU4mY6@iKNDLh9OODEqr8qrrWPpAoXQwMFiWoqLqcniE8xreqhSAjDc3eAo@uQWiw5xmEHVr5IDyQmveyBpYgoOnWSvLHAxBF8aFccNNymELptIoPdAQQFdWwrIRA6Y3oK3/DOpJ5E37q6pW4u1azWg5RQyiLXV/iLvRN0B1SsBoBaRIXnllzTvNO2wOXBohXQUSY/IWTXJ4DMcCi4EgSbOmqOcHxCFugfOlyCuIRq@nOJsLXErJZ3JFtZBXQC0DNQ1kVgnn3KSRPukOpYkjATzJ6dO8QaQV9r2ubvflLd8RIAty30dQ1GzjRbNpt0BAb94h3HDduTFvNdRWssquJ9ny4yer0HqXiodtN/CAtktOaJr0ZGv4WU@/zs56OvWuHlMmo7E/5khj9mgPBKk3DvDrnhHte5hAiQYqW0txFYz8VlkxIWRhUgFvSCkFOhSMtND0FMRLAqEXxUNoOcC3IgnYYjaDl4Pv74jwEVS6sd2bTtyjNRKUa3C21BsDEWmyuYtc2sP5wQmMjmHLRy4NlYtMmp0ZcZxH1z0@WwmJ/DX@ID3oaiEEmpUPZ6TtcFcDNAJKReo5cA5oVzhtOlzMMqLSDy0NMiSccPIBJAibVg8GwGcgMS/IHi8Iz4l8lot0YjtnNkLrGKwkdcwJn@x3pi6udZu9aNkgelbjcQAaFS7C12lRvGN0@SwrT0ylACVQZyNj5OBUAkhXxAoMKoLOF9RRF/Rwxhq6VUbCFUOAL7HdfeBiXYPPF0kjVKKgSR2w@MRV9qQvFF16A635BtkKCx@pYr/SjwMCLG9voFkSfwaUpBNnRJE@o/kWDLwbiLsCrhhCiaGFiXrNGRv2VZ2Pa4SJZJW2IcTjfBHoPL6xsRGvxOvxNLh2wLWNrh10pcC1Qy6JXBhPRhelSJMLQxuUAv1a8ctGAHmWbGEbmKHk8MYcJ/RGpZJtpfWG6j81fCahKoDyEFvCB8CJJ2s1dCaTYv0M12xAfo@UfR/bzrOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9mSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt53uylmpfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXz0uQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRfXMGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/cIYD@duNEI46wZSNs6gL/aq4JYe5OJRLvmGp48KdEuafiD38ngg3OLkHcpL4znn7gLHtKks7YwKxt1TqT9yJrryqQxKkxwZLuMbcUWSYCSkEA6Jiv3I9LAL67bhTL3oTOPKCVDMHXyPh1NglsH2tDS0KnMsGN2hw@KbuwCdhes9OJTg0pXEF8ACAL2uDD9koiiV4GIJSBe0ocgEvkhbsWhWRiUkOOsJ5ubzhfFrOcytSmlYBjMyB7bjGhKQBFIItHuK9uQJ9WBd@pBmvq6tS/ihNKSh4m0awBHvW45OtOXsOrIeNB5F0oN@DkmeGj3BAv7RB/Yo87pwjZ6yJdAqreMOYYSA0iAn1sLaGvkBiuONe/JkBkmFBA640UCu3YHQecZ6mqYVuvl@JQjDVgHEHkIloVZqg4obBEkqBCb9Sj7g00KBjv746N4BnzuhwRaHV5xHa4@c3hTkSl9vemrYgzQ7gPZk2s7IBDIE6d@cWE8dZ8K1fHhZNzPDlWZzNLV0mvO5Oi1zY7qu03Esmgq6Keki/tT1dEvnk1BB6N6nj0DWf378rCZXIpEU/XR0Y944D7k6W07Pw@iaI623BstDHm@Y4mZexHEr2PWJbMYPKGDA1N/zCXUU@BfRP@hSuIbi@5fQf4T7PUFW9mcR6DX09COWKSLuAcUNb77nuZq5RP@1OlgYT6V4XHBcYHuuauR/Oun3l7yz5H0iIWuyFt458uZ7QZd0xChKeR4JN4YuxYkCKlCccH/o2nhFisd3t8jhyuKjcBPC0LCCpcWnILHg8hkM@hbKVaC0oIjO93AaIGGPcZWEWDeuvbEuCKHetfkM6GxjiccWYhvUgWBwU1CkETYV5s99V6kL2Y6/ZulxtuqAzk/TKtt1vsqNOpXL1TmFz8pvtgHEdr0abLhbFw1zisfDaASVcIMUVExa2L9W1HCbhkeT7QIlqQqeAurETMtIzVnxoHURVzwiQ5@Jzebso4z2OegluFty844yMKq0x2kNvapBSNyXYTtzJoHEh7H4xHV3CHyGpWbLpIT6mdp9x@pJfJUMGgzj@hVWkL9JIdzF6W/WNUw32MBJO2h5UuSvkb2f1@BeqdL69QiR3aIhIOg@5@ziJH16wRow5J3K3tgyJy12KU@c9tDfKWVf3VfKZVDX1eee4O9xqbG9px9/2si0OARhpOPKV4nX4izYngyCMwhKuI8cXLhTZ2JOSBKgnQgmlleVAakZLZIA@gCDZ1BlYUZ@iRD1C@NiUZa@AZpqwkDMvfkozYzkpdy39MnEsHmb48uP68nN14n8bGqU/Y6/6FBhGVqZAcnUxDBAscqeHd87ePpUhpbrJeIHuIJTge6od4cgoKwrdEDJaOEr7KNenH2EaZKotgvQ1UD7aPvpoVFXodGD/gG5I@8YGG4CPJO4@NIFb1rvooRcQvMJhPutuhOiUQgsYSShTASsshL/5zZXtXw8K9DiU0RJIHfiTgVoayblqW2@lj0YaEhuhShxrqzCeFHbTBAX21ST/oa6ES4dg4ZFQiOUoNFg0hvgchBZZK1Wle8BgLiogLkDpK4oUlXQLvaaGlR9DbxBpCEIfvLaW/aikZHKrdTmKlC0uczfgM7LH4GLEJZBe8bKbDcT1N@vdWSOA18L5Jz7OanTV05fVNgmd4h8zpmiBxumiOnQ/qrlfVLLu7CgkyEroakYLEjAEmL@8QC/zVI4cX7QeTAZeSSS7DwkuoYkZxcXREO2qTGiIbhUxivjMtA@gTE9dKA0D/2jAVHpgHqrv5EE@2xTEAM1a3mlFkO4CK@cXpFOpVMxmo5Lh6Z94tB6T@hqZ2Q1jxJhmHp0Yl1PiZtQ6bYUNcSBx9XWYeeNOn26rYhAyx7@gjp50IS6LwuDEKkrT@lBc@srcl7eRLKUrb89lUZacDPp9S0xpXKJIvc7HXNdVCAC7gsLniuiAZPC9qzJOVkNzhrgVAyMR8C4uPayKPrV/Udsie7@Plr/@Z@/0QP6X6@dIQwUOPMYOtowdGNNSf21leUnxRe6ra5YPkE@tUydCEOu20B2dReKpFuhYzVoWoSXJBj@R7ik4Nc4tE28gdR4QzPjmPMVweC5OpNVi2o2sMzuurhX9mPxrGj5BxS7HhGBC0GmQYmIdfFKMGZ8CSaiYiMbux2pYNMUo8bM6304nUz5HQTXWyvRHOPvpr7px8zk9Y5qKHzn@g1V7uon054jjU8GoZxaWBF3UXpaA5ZAHPCXg9voXF18XkC@Ezx4rou2GNqUM3rc1io8e@qNpQ5p4T3@Rh1hdEMOrsXv66KY/uG90LGeaqZFt/dsiT50aCj@bggF95pKEaKZV8hs6Z05yiDDD29l4c4C4Di1biqVya5ZWh6P16dHTZLSl8urU8/kLqfHqjkChe9nlfgsGhXY3@F6S63CcGWOdEvSehHnWma@amPCtajhmialwcMXdALjxkaOA1J3aunuwnVDE1/gESwjrJuR9oeNJ2bXAXFgzNSirGrB0BEZMIhlBlvjFhnhdmK6RbY/mKvIGBwnkULXahbgdCe4ZXRNm3oPhsa3auKG2EgjkZ11lOo6Z/hbKz4MQTXl99Uj2puVWL0Hc5KsrqXDOL52OFiaHMTJx1sa6pnpGXRbTdiTlYhOutZK/@UuEEz7RafxbmvWnmk5HntG95sINHCBCvy@ukFHaWnqtkST4VH3DTwo2OOwqFDdGjhWoTRQdLitrfWp20e@7z/fl8OFHEpVb@FQgfjj2Kr/XMvXTxT35LYKogOLLu5vjThvGGJXsSl/7WV96UAxwIW71SW7nylRSlnhU31rMsYllzN9Hjx/jqFjHWmDoWM8J3EapDtMUC6BY@JyEfvnyS13c26992NK18AWbytEpHJPLAMGK7pfq1KmZdQPTKFmMu/PovrW1JgaKxWNo84rA4/V36BkvD9SGb8Ym/5MPS4O4NGUMNYbXzN8L6xxnMa3G5mJbpld43ZRZpmpjUH6HqPq/AQcT9BxPcXAno6XanVJO7Of3kyy4Tjo0k5vCTsM@VA@VLpFUlqSzz2DfjdqTFzDww1itXwmk/EFmMiKy9LLTZpUNkz7yuT3pYzJZ5HzIi6usrkR5@o8iCzRLYhrWZC2TrGnyOWyYpu2MZnj/T25acdxrA@pKWCqeGDYAW1Voq22N9XYNXHHP0TCFlMXHk54dPrrJi34aOPrlkAfVJpvqvToktB71aaEi54jXJBafr15@iaywHRbLni4FeeE@OZba70s6c@GqHJJLt7Y67iE6nQMS@ePWSF3E7yynL0R3jLT8BdrcXGXL@kuluJjV5jSeA7EMnugpQyNkUGvN0j5eg9NZPiPtZFmDv7WBc8Mo6vMDozuughjE/iCjfelNeSIsDRxbNCvJrjPD/UUC3eS@r7rOHCw6reSyIcjfWBwmy03ccrFhAXupuFq3cK5euqiwnfQdCHZwhjH@iYBnerEmHvBcyXAR/Mu1Ot0dPt025XO38U50Pfo7eu2sF4fYu2hM7SHxpDvGw/f1nUOaI8TbmPnJtQB68EQt7KNx0tb3KP0tBzLeh96ImvkjNJx@itxOsDDr3hy64Pg8pP2/uPWyTt9wnkHOtb2mqExhXHJcybO2JDobV1UCyd6@H0dDw0WqX/eGaQb9XygSPD8eeHfqlsOdGcyHtOjPbamHt0oqURnlm@Tm/p8awptinTcgfzGGXVk31P2963QEvhqFtMxJ90hHhrnLdsYOJ3u0LwNad9QhRJM@fDX99JdkTImk@6ht2yZQF53LmN7qUXDn@HjcF2l@7NHfFgLHTfIK6tm6OhYtjTWT7oenw1FF6vghHCkN/LD2xU6/l55PTUnC6CRvUzh9C5flkDHOtz93RNrJSs6I7Fgw/6uirWtlIR0FMglIwMCj7ou2@V9bpEuls3y2zqEoqUkjCL7Uj6E3P7eH5odNCPztuC/1L6WNi2tHOTs4XTgXWeYfLq@ByIa3tZPW9Be5siUNYxZuu0/1pFZsxQ85AjPNshcU@PGNZX8jYsqFE@1JN0x4dGGB1TddO0cmmWOPX5nUn/tUpy/lwl08avrhZw289XKtF8xPaPPl0DQdZuIOHJc3IkMMojUxZV0nEFHZs4FL864bGcATF2y2CJyEHed2LJym9Dq6g/HTOnzx8ZAx73WD80JbtZc0Sqoya7aXnQr7K9Pdc/8@hRKtq6xocUGvgzpRo/249sKeI/0gdl9sFQRIZI@gf2dnvyx1PzR63pdnA1ND3c0hY4bJqawyfFGjK2uDXrDiphX5@1DYxWLDsSPQa6MvWpu3RnP8bTYnFw3TaubE5pl9Z/rVMd1m8BuROJsOhpPPf@xGgfaMxWdhR6dkL93ZgJw6TWwVjbUrcnqmerIlCtIYf6guHCuk8a/MC1nwL4oZRgIbSCEoXC@ouHcheH5CW7Ice0VLZHyfs9lT5zokFxesNdQt0aWSaZtTm6ezZlMcHNO8MTC8JEDTygoD/Eu734oBOl4NUUe3i7rL44m3zK@Q8t75kzdroHO0N5IVC3wczX2g93HeKLDQXspZ1EtretY0L3AYa3sMl3Hnk4kd2rfOCoUbhwVKmhtKtIMWOLrB4@eJ6OtgXZr3yaFBvbIFq61GwauNDLTBkFsPR9djh3oEve4naSntFX4ljR7aMypS@z6nrNK33kyhwHkvRUmYP7T0T2ji8uGt@b92Hnk2A6MRmNglKOnBj/zv7TRY3VCTPYQT7UDfXq3ZvOMwK4ZhLi0oY@NDtSvtXC9z1jEAd/TJ/qaoYjmBkn/C123thXT6hjuK5r0i7jXqbTLCD0wZqRbrG8wvA9Kk26Xi8Q4H7fUR5ZWbLyx49j8Ttw2Aw/10c1cBYYCur3/QrmMG/GX5gVW6mfLRT065btEjB43SrGurK7RcSx@v2FPkm3yPQG6axqe8hBtHJBfIcckkL68G3lI8UYeslCNQJI91T1apF@taixAqrMP2AI01N2ugythvuOG3TkRwwS3sOlwbz/fONABws@AY@ndqW8s9Da0rFFnRLe1CkOkNp8aHTwV1CFrHhN9dr0y@cyQb8ogsqMrNAAQsCvs1AWWeALaSPL2YWtJj1qmqjmmG3HqtcvltFlHsk2j@0bHWTOH6LWYm14KhzIrj8m5Zq460o1oFlnR6aT7yp60vHUNBBrLkCZDF3R@ZXLT9HZgZmXFesh0ZOAi8/IqzFrR1fGGVFhn9Xp6yFxdQ/Jt/QEvCe3@cflQ2lsreSJ4@D@6@4kCg3C7kAtMjwDrun0FH5Cfurb/eJ8W@MTxJn1zdgR44ymAdewEi5WHJPDgPQNdW@sKAbVnTy0@@zCI7Lsa9Ugdk8gKsyRZxK4nhmTYpxIZgptdL5HDD30pe2i9d2L0JN8OAq40SA@D819hNP@5YgE1yhtxs6eqcMLOCjl/@@cq4p4FnAHkLWcijT16KmPvyeHDo2N57Kkrx6e9IZ6OuCbHLRlW0EqZyJTUK92NrHfy7Wg905sod5@p0v7DQxkjrKE3X9GQ4IErc0uPtfOegRVXRV@rBWGoMVktID44fvQwtTiiyRL7Q9cZGclo8P6zZ2k8afLJs5XB0dT3oXf0ndna5IcHqppc0Xyf27Q6uI57rshpHaRjA7RRaIwPuF2WW4WrrjM2esfzsfEpDJ7Iwb33zL6wtpCP9VNzgL2QldcSijoqK8uFXDKyMxuUbcMNn@vq88QcI7fs0kPhj7XbUVByyCpudrX0cNOK/1UphmX8nQgflkjNXG@tUTvCiu79fRFTVXUdnZ/pfahXll9bWcsRVq0PW87peywlG77yIoVe0gRalWTeuo@8KI2AdSt4w@l53xOcnbXbYG4CEHoXVnb4M8Oe67ZEa1k3iRcVSI2b2m6M8oXxHgtS4Q6fUzRWvnKNL9xSzxJdciZvyfjYjSTZ3797eFuCpz4tb4718ePn7InuoRGSmyNGMTbeA@OFZPRKwnkrtIC3djm15wIo7UZ4g/Hq/lxhz3S359jz2e2LcHQGFYd2Mi4cwsI3imRY5sxcNVZ1@bzWk9XbjG7Lmx/icOZLcnDUOI0P6N23/5mqZjJkegifaoa/3lIzQQdnCXTpc7RnFw06PgxZQxflFhk8kiu10YfGDLej8NngVUr9yvGtcMPYV0yuH05uCivdEJa7Ib9rYejJsnJGvQFg/oYwlpfD4IeOdTZ05H3dNbwV@49XInRTQco3FKQc4c6@tXRaWPTd60V8PLrgP1a21mNj4ubGQ6dj5laWYa@PRibZIzSWfj3c306hu7S9ZeD4Rz74@@r8zqbGyowe6W9WBxCnOVkZBEzQGE7pSMT14OUF0g7IvIY9MLl9RXbXmRzQ2w2KWXjiefVeBHN8bzpejzHwRvwkxVV2vhTxM9CZnTOP3cWjcQsxfYXuj/vjVvuvk2lZODGIZkYfHO8FrevomaJFclxg8fmTJW88PDo5ehbxc43ZbJ3SK83W6ZArQxa5Pj7OLWW7XX9xuoJY688bgbgB/Dh8rpWDOLP75Nl1loDq23AysoKQT3R7MWO6VGE9Z0InDVcGPpnPaBvlypoe8l1sq8Lc7grvJcUeBmTThLw9pd1Gy/rt9rpWeWx8TmsPIAaxCRdLOFDf8JIxyw0DDCnJ2o7qnCyEnyV0n42Hpj1bGTRal4Z2kSZeeau7wR57Zjln7GFoVWgde9BWA9dPDXsdc1p1WFEqZ2@WwrJXRKp19cK/XuI/1lXJ3XWC2hWegRsibuImmP5pV7kfvHyqJW@N/8mzIPrtcfctB@fve@Z0dHtkAptK3R7RvYH9XQVo3h4NP/ZxMnRc@/aoQXOqVO4a74nExnvHHM27znvg0On3b4904Dm3R3o0tSYm6iyroz52phZaEFgVduAOrvvzg9XQL6NG@b20b1aJGyLgx789OfhyQiJhQ5Unlz9TFT3LjqarE5tounWTzq1D3IsLtuGfFYcAMTh97p@ORwuPpj018Hg7/3jNpLYJ2dRqar7MdvC7UBWmZihP/NRdmRvSCzJrsM1z/@R3paJeso0aEysi88/eh3axuW1nAIxWaaFQTDpR2eYEQjaDc@OMPlPCLhhNd4F@reYz8CYrUQsaVf9kPeC0ef7k8MnBs@O94@fPGpnWpX/yPiiFbUNugX2Pj7I9EQrv0w3EaG7pnSw@WJAdfUIFp8m8oFwMP8u0XLTaUtEWhRJ3MM3muW0rChkfUKRLwE8SeW4UioMBeHHYQYmpgny7ExVuB4DMGUAdcdAi5QmVVmGZVRmPdRAJN20//OpXzCgUv3JXwe/cYca@cW5oiQPH6fk5ega7/QpyvL93@PD50wMWILhoNWdmbzKslfPcdjs3iAL11DdpN2aNxf0kcairWi1@Pw6EictxViFzEWQ3HRo6RAuog4Ym/NRbLLFJ8IGC8bBSlP/8DeUyLuPBgiTEjQdIxSFbaPPUUDY2NtgxNBJ27@nhpwdPGeJ/cI@8kUQIgh3jWfU/@3GPf3kksCUVfOHPHZH8RrZ4hKi9isCIw8LOBNKc@u54/Xf@6EsfZM0h/MRI@I0kQaAv0EC7PSMzkFdMBCbJahf/LqFvwTHIiJpQ8LUCXMNCa4yux05Nz0RbEohDH40jLjd23PZGBkFltocfMcRPJer0GRxAfWpPuAEy3wxRDFqaHPKcNNskZPlHc8RIxPj2BjT2jgGiPfNsEwTFSYW9gpaI60QVbmtEkurxa0kC0BVySSgORiJes6boKU1Xefdr/0QZVBm4J@D@ju@eZe7C26/4b31w/yp3v1CwoV23vrjAJYoQWkz1S8ARCemPtI98u9Hm9l0WhEMjkQFjZeYIqumUqI7ReQ78LgE/XsBJND6FSoPmBjXm23Xh@RluK4EmWyuKgk0K1U2ZTtUYM77F9Yrp1kK@kFMVQFI6DQDStxYGeHafA0wmK9BNhFNzXHsJKsz29jYTcc7JqBWqvGaVTftFVnwZIroJcYWzISLXYJAGkixSQFjdTwajT0pNYlLkXnE1joyr58CwROE4fOG77RNCZAkgFqeRgcb7Z/iZzwlIYr4J4g5@GDPyHZ5NH5CkwphErqQo@BZRHjsTaD7QSRdf2uIWUXCLNx8C0banxz9@S5Z/sT3K13vW4iB/8MEfv6/JyAM4qGzm6mgarVvxMwTxDEFUxFXNt/GCNSdNu6Xwtsmgmf5wRWO2wf3LymBNm@Xl3rtu9zVx1WorEovtPrMdnFy7D4VhCU3RsopaSC6KlMutLJJfIj8bKA4al7qA7IBNAcvoGuYrZ@zt7R8cfnL05Nk126YUM341GvD9@naqKcnpRit0xKPFWq6Su/eVZ4/u3g8qYoF0IcKNgfH7JVFvKslizhxBLs5gXS3aKgyvlm49xp9xKw1X8c1qN6FGia7hoWY@IF86ByHdp9OMVzPXSquolc/fhNICnhIBvc@Pol9DNZE8v2y0tutNOxa/3hJWdIQXMXkLOwG4mt7WpoKN/XrhsGDhZ6mP8YN/XrQvZlf3RXEzi6bz0BLGxDlZGBf0PSIBkfIG2QCLFGQliLq29x1xIX1hAlPjn83mNveiFsUiCBcyN1E8Auo4@AI3cpGFAV/fdu1Q94aW2RECS27chm1gajM0X8utsCWSgv8ZGJ5xwv8m96wyk2nTYyKJ3I5gpdlN5nADeEkBOjRKd0@m3pA9ccb8swC0ueWeEbieOsB@7035ZJjBPpmOIF6fHk8NWmgEzi1BYqBkPESVy1LAJXxruLMU2huG/BpoE9cvuDzq5ROzpDw0Zj1zALw9kUwDR/tIVVsstJiLhSYLuXZcpDpb1MKNXfFjNDAQJfsHmU2eLRDQG7ps2j1jloifxZOVFuSP/vGzz07jSXFVWyLzzb49495VO84h@kX1Zk6iT/zeGRhJXsUtyuXrXAL8rgLm9gSDb5KVy/LQE@gbkzWU3J9N3IfgBDEi0R/pY5aY2twWo8zoNdFM2GkyUifVuZ1Xm6VSpFDBgwJkRin75OLjd0K35yyh1PAzpODr2T18vDHHrKHKcgvclEmSbeK3AvdB4kLrpEkBlGBIUiGwNWxCoGYARryTyLyBQxoMh7jwIIuWK4Lp02m0HuMgTajUrH6HRb79uCw5iuVyxa/QZa5YZtD6rrNDWQGw1/hcINcDdX0zTUAzUH9lIbZg5Nc5XozyjXFEHvj2nQCdWMQ2c2D2iQGsheXk7tDFX@LAhr4C8kGl8vz4fruUVEQW2okauGYP1wv55wVCFc//IBR0U2UparzKNbqPMRla5GxzQ1RoGPI@dRjxCkuNRcngWzUOlGVv0TZV9cZW7yf0awFi5nAA8M/TtgNwaEU1mEhcEbaa2f/sZzEUNhKbqnrSdk9T8XymCje1mmd59tFmU5I2G5na7qYOWtTk9awJOrmylbt3agz7vcOB0hRFlmU5Rdk6Pz@P3996Yr7Is4LUM7XC69n8MlvIvp5dZtXS65OxWmjIr2ctsVRLn7TYkyefv22/TYqz0/lrsZnQYvtHF6KaQ5U/Vimz851CNnZSBvUT8mXshL2B66TP8J/cb3oRt47uTh9U2LjIYs0mUFwVi6KiNOIt@Cd1/yVcXPFv1OW6vNN6@zbZ0PXJbM5M0xx7vR78nCFIkFryGQN9@Q5wep5AYU16kgaF12jWvz6fkGdstmcMBtMDva7hUWt5t12dm9P7k0dffBZcz/F68zSS7I3/ceJUKiFJjRXzFJW2no/hZ47/7Ccbl@nzJ@3tP/vmSDE28HGEj@9cPkL3MzX/0cbGR3fv5nJpTdO4@8kXT35xb28vdy@df9LI7@SkzMb2n/7JxoambWvKRsvz1Fa8cXLyuahlcqL8Zz@Kt588@brn1bP/5zfe1lW8FeF2yorAJ@DKMhWceC/BT0UZ632v2JsYtHI1Nqe/dizwP99gan2n@F@@d/Q6NonVNeUzF56T2OtYoRTjTnDAWzZ4O43VY9sYrXAZmyu1Wg2cxf/ybyF9/ROAgyHzbbjV8wGswjxWl2qU5CJWL4BD1TTI9//@xjciGHI2USMxLrh2WQMuMVfUxJ0WXFt0bQtof1PKKEoQz54MJ4bD1NId9Q6@mPACD9vADxkYk2YMP/TOjnYZe9pIpVItuS3BJb@gSSJFVbWmqt4BdiB9tFWrSVuMWxjNZvN30Ep6kqa0Bg6MmMadz/4hrtgqz@rPDe6pECts7L68V69DmbL17FY9RZffkahPFUui4@yKLM1exkEFabRePmTcLHJdzJQ0MZ1O77bpfYa0kmZhS8KL32Ox0Ae7LLvqt5QEovi@sQ@PFzvA68//tz///p9/j/6@T7//gAZK7Z7ZV7Yg0il0iTpcu5VKt14X66543sT3OrSjTKVUKSnty2ZiCzhQ6ylTMx9fxPPZ@DP@EXaVsWaSUsNF2db97PG9Hlt417lPPernB/DI5MH8UpBjiWrkDql2LR4Mrf5WbqlxWm9JKBDVpIZayLcknqoeXGXW2IVqErViWWzVtbx2xHbbM36x4abHnBhohoWAjj6@9UXZ6mHI4q0e9YrVg2T1RZwPjRfiK8QaDaVl0IAQ@LHdjcpGqVKoaEq7vv6Cphl9paiGYTzxYqex8OKUjS0IGgub5lW/oCrCFxa0YPYh8aCy3meym2opW1DFqu/S2kysQiPRspI2aIsZVQx7G87vw7UBf/QPV/iK9w3y8b0pyvVrg1XULS2r5D8qHGg4vt5yRXEVYJxg3U6n86bbAalD1zt6V1cn@lSf6XN90pl2Zp1Jd9pl2GWWZ/SzTt4pOTM2o39ZimXz6mbsDjXqt40N9pRzoRZLBVczdev1XJbbvpMcDv4kyZnFhNg/wFVXNZVtwfiUgRsIZeQEnRn/VFVgMRC0zltvtxpvt6CD1lPbxBxbdcnHEh5ye7eVki4vG@CuVv3/7XrorNLFXVC41mUqtf2iDtLHi3ojBSBf@CBliRFQuV1vbVNImJmfmx@83QL5RUptN7Zrzj79ZOogUgsgbi9hububksG1Cynrm6DApjYlaQOHxIY/REDUVj0VFAazToCQcH7@Pr94zokXnN0VQaDmQR@@3L6sXza2Ly@3t@F/m@6X/hN8L7ev/dNjca2JswhvIWNpNpR6U2n6rKIF77JSRx9ZaYKjDk@I18hqpVYDHXDJrf82/@X04h76IMotGbAWYltsK4bGMrOxLSH28t2X/wv@mu@@/H2UFhn8GRUhdo6dWtlCXbPMVU64MfuRzR7xywY3/oJX9EGPR3X0tPnNxuUoRXkpswqf8U@opUJSxuG37fTbaH9DZi8h6jXOx0StVBDbKXWusdi2WCgSs/uFa1c8Hv9HL7VyMc6nadCAxEvP8x5FsFzgCZGrWkaV1Is6/0YC/5zNL6y6/tEvrLuE2EWZGRWgT4JxwggxaEcxRZEkGK7q2yM8YYALJRLqpKe1z6XnexJOougTWgbr8gmC2uFBrVyu8zWezSfUebbubcFdhf@DDSgGa/YhbrNf645A/G32s3mtiQb1Y1LnNf49fIN/7LiLf09f4x87foN/Tyf4xx518O/4Nf7tdfDveIR/d1/j36M3@Pd8gH/Nr2SzalXcPCfKpNSyerk5E4lC1dhOvfmViTuvWIbdMHst/1tR2VyZJWPNrxizrjGeVLhnP/7T737zm/FaLS7F6Qs8OdVxmZqMMYyInxFlLFmFmlAzKpTQi1d3419pkIqeL7caGKUFoUKsxjbVTTVjZboZtaN2wGGyjMsyw8xQ7amkymQMlpln5iwzctQeuAz4y4DLzPRZZsAydsaGaBAKrkk7M0FXHx4D@OsDIBf@TNxT21EzXQYZWSjU0fc91TamzFy0m0KDxZn40gBdVFbljFwwW/hVpIb48mVT2Wpp5RKTsdnJ7cbLZrwlNkW0lK@Vc6wzNzaaL0UYujMib57ow2KeBwpuNaY0mwqnJBCJCH152W4fPL7Xbis4TDUfOUeL/6OjUfT1xv/RkfPoyBk58H90dASdy6indlPAx3d3a8DX/cdOrF7daVZoWAiGhpiyvdOsZyV0F1LA9DX0S33gtYAIz/pGU4ifgYJxBrpJNQEayln1tFo9I8dn/BUcbXSjZ/h/5jv8J0GohvrNGVynBJbe0Hn2WTN0cYfy2Rl4fcZALwv/QQGMvv5X@Df/2/p/9JwlWaLRSibOL7cTdCXxL5k8vzy/9O/1ZCLhvyS24Q894B2TnF/W0UmRzsHVSCRbyctL7gf3RHKbA6xDNtt1SruIBwNHLMySsuW3xH/dJ2TtX814FeRirnvnM9SPYmKV6Yt9N83mLJNJVjvBR0BwFVm/oM0NySp9AXKz01Bbf/oj@tDLTpIi5XPVqrrF@IuW06rVXPBWLFWrpeBlM5EoX7/qmR21APpJLpdMVqvwshOAzcArpG2wtylWY024t@7c4ZmUtIuLAGY2V0hlcL9TtRrklIdsDU/v@jz5/PCIvpECrCYfw48TcVaSyNAXlvArfnGxIt65k@gZuHG7t7OXvHNHK2cuLkKf8Ri81CWvdrtnuu02@mcvLsS2SPtkynl4z5QuLtRMOaXGk46beIyff4SsEpLKPtLqlGsZOL2WK0Kwj0B@e7uQq9cLOfAplOJJXHPnLB7wjYvxqhg7pzKopSLngGIVvaP7h6Av4zjBzi9jVKEsl08mgJEmQUq8jOGfizyXj0j5fBIocynymGq5zKMmWa6QKKXK/l9tA7R2EIP4H8py2VRuq7i1CzIx/nmzVRfy5Oq5UVMva@dGBWfdL6td/0PaaGfEuHMnWwYSlTLVptBu39s73mu3azCWoSgFN/Qk7i6g@RU3XqnuUr2qpTyDCuSeUhyGBFYCKivaVl4tIVUEs492g4AGAlefNtiGoNETb0KZk2oDPEG/gdx6cLEe67ABXmyA2hwzmUUXsxgPp3u3G0Zy@OWHhq@UlhS@wMcIL8HvdlneJmHUfvJwb//gOK1tSyym3d/bT2vPnt@NqfiaX7xTcBbfnx7s3Tt6DgmePDzYe3bw8eGnB8@fgL/HzhZXwOX9@@IZda14P2OfCa/cN7ph6MbUMNpn0@nZa/bKNNsm1J41hUI5A5d5RhvKMtYX5arCr2t6@qtXujumi7374bff/fC/e/c73333O99@9zvf/@mX3/82/H4Mv@/y53f/TTmP959@@c9@991v/w54/gf4/RH8fvLTL3/jG/xH738Mv/8U8ftj/xeJx38CwPqVn375vR/99Mtf/QH8/qX/@8H136/9ZPXv@99a/8N03/vdm@N899/C7/c4rCDud3@b@@HzWvzf5vF@9Qfv/sW/4/9/6v@h83fe/Ys/xpv/8k9/8Kf/6d03/72mlf70X7/71vfefeub7771nXff@sfau9/412omevvdd9//g7/6w9/7qz/8H@n/x3T/vff5f/eDf/oX/@tf/O9/8Yf@7yfw@3fg@slf/HvoKn/7Bz/E/@/9wd/@0Q/x/3/@V3/7B7/@t7/yP5HjN7nj//mX/4bf//rX/uPf/NZ3/uon3/ibX//J3/zmH/zV//Gr/9dv/Me//u9//6//yTfR8zd/8ld/9Ct/@c1v/@W3/vlffvPLNfdv33j/8j38v/wH8Hl/PN8HzvuU60N9vvy58Pn7UGORC7QTaN2//O43fgka@L9g7N23f4xH8uC35v/Hmkpxfszf/j/g0K6XGUMy4ILfr7/79neRRP8DkAj@Q3p9J3xZCuEv31m8AFl/a0WiX/7pl//8R/QWMyp1WsbBwbqklVJboNBslcv@gO2v8ECSX1qGFgLwc/oOcqilsO8gb3v3w2@8@9E/fvfD33z3w1/B0VrKldN7aUm9ZXkMIubfIx5GLLxPPIz4Oeafoqk3KfU5vLHP/cDPP/9caF8oePZz9wJ8PycvfjEehGdD/aAgDP3xsCi7YFG378z4zk3fN8yZscbLly1cgAU/zD1FssdWIAvls2yW8hGbMb7Og/4QabZFzhneyReDZwLeFv8L50xgKZr85UsQqYWTHH46PwvuFPKQTWoWri6RcMa4dLTFfWjhmPLNlRmWYDZLzUDrBQfkkIKguyB/12opTFjj@MArR61eYoRKKlWDcmNqnibdLiGI2V2CAilrqaesvVWb8YQphFcPyJES0OupqGpiqlS7BxnWZvcYwkLgBPbly1q9VJvVEdxbTo/ULHWXcEJgtdSs/hbeawQT0gmxe28BlVItlaqXMEMsJK@edJtXUp4KR2VPsZRfB/DE/f87u4x9JKolka8abCDBeGy8pxaxMSJEh/BmassvDv0HTvptEcE3KCs/F8bDd0g23eHiKkYAuJIkyzKDHy7I77BdCJ5xUCnKFh4pDiFFLYJaQOjBcEIoJaSoflP0AvnHalsffCEwLMzm5qYQq4tZ8Ugm0ikKc08qdBgC9weiPlFhYqEsordBJ0MCXCB9lfLfjONKW5xxwOyjFP/t7m6xj6CY9Fz4CUxKZZ2cE@NQtlMpUQP4dSclvAA9RIB2SoAuBHlWo5W9lJBOMybXYhjGjo6OfCTI40VNSEEz17IqvuP60nQ6jUEKWU7L6bT/lOlJHrLvkCnUf8qbSFz6IDrTtFwV1KUqQy8W1W1U0HnR8@3bt1ArtOGqcgjaJvP3Xmm5EgWCBzeBY1nz4AiRlisLXBVnaiHHWIJmXeFKMjwrk4CGlBT4Rn2ORnAl4lqpFKeYQH85sRVsxiuo1CBw0jVWR1SDi2uBpXwyCNw/YvtHjx4dPD4et1pMMOgT70Z77Dpdw/MSGLb3@B4/pKGVC8lYo4GgjysashjhoJIhdnx47@nhswrjxfYrIUGIVWmp1S9oWRVi4/Fn2zF/M5KIXyl0xGd4ryzKltDKWUgaqwuxroG6Ba6ho85bZVXhkTe468xAjU@LYlotoG6XxBVDwOMXnSlDG7rc4A70Kjy6IW9vEwWE@rlE6xnohPoqCPW6v42PqUL92cExJDg@YqqWkYX652wmY4bSpVC3apZhDybDTdwPJzYzYqRMm41MGv@0bBbuaq6QVvPF1saGdS5hnk2qtnPc2HgJr@cSFuOrcDHhqwL7KnjBBXngbkXmbxU9PKr6@/XQWl2Cb9oT1Tx0tKSAs9scnDCOXlVo38urQ0Js44svJqxeB5VaOrwvxIBfDFmwZU0ye/JQpmruTV2DQgeM9cxPTfz8pNwzvbGlz6HzADVil5eXfYB0eJ9pdY1eeYoe3i@75NMB9@VMF2J2pVJ7q@aKgnZSqbzNapoAHsKWgnviNqAB0NaCLYX/VT3IJJstKcCrVFGERzabFXC6WBAqhsBo@8jbTK0m8TaYzam0e0TAL5ros5oWXn7c2UeLuNkMj4shEMAGE5dlgrAiD/PfCgK9AdFwwxx9P7vqd8/MnTtZnLfI5jLhBAWVmF1C3Wxmc1mkOB5IasVyRX/lRBTFVkywjAnr1cAda8KNz8Fpakxk@IZsI1vKCLFGrCH8//3yF4e2x/VsRt1WxuDUwZnbVnRwdsCZ31Y64DTBWd5WTHBO61k1s61M6wITtrmhW4Z2dGrixJihXW3uJ9Y9w@rLeE6pJlIGmrjtG46vBwnrvVrP6U5xi0i1J5u2bbh46p0nyOXEqmOjCcYaGmMhOwEskTwXBrUzOpsvGLWBjFZ9XFu3hJ7ccXpz2ZvMLTzxYzluLQ6SZDwIWEA3QITBebKdbDZXabCWPHbGO4KWL6YaagbGHvyppbSW3jB2isVKT@5ahu7u5Cv5UrqHh4n8FbOdfKYykD9/9PDBZDJ@atAJo51cGRKgHTy0WLVTquTzrUZDFFMNyqaF3/zmfE3a2ABmYOg9CZ64nuZJWqkFiXumW6vF4ztZVZPUSjZTuhQWhEOaYwnrAiZNYcnSSPdzn3VUbMcGLlVJ62nznKhQ6ff7l1vnqcWLoJ9L/A3ocynp6c55@FqVIvEqbJqWzEUg@Oh9IPe5v1RYEbV8Saw2qov3YkGsti6F3ZHRM3U8WNTMnF9PVQBuzqHGIKMmEy4rruNMKh2j77jGImJWLQQROULXI@TEyzC7ZgZzPL@eXSESaXZ@HUouL16GqQK0hMtLoDsnNpDdt2Jcpw24DbWcax0A74Lmsx0YOMZosRcvhNjW00@z9TpU9XmuqOXyubyWLRTyRQ0GqnKukC9BZ8sUMnlNAyi5cqlcvIR2rShvY/T9QrZ/HrT3Cn3BIaFXuAnSRosl3z42rfNSVuJ4JJLVy8vYWyH20dNPNRhZ114JGK0/1aR6LZsvgyuLLi0LCDNB0yQtK2VVSc3i/y0ODf/fP74G/xreIVVWE47RLtFjGG9BRrDZQ7RvMnHYsYNfuBqwu0Z3TYz9oU67o/ddx/P@HnHu6vYJD7pncmPAYdADHT/z543MyXBNjOfjEZo0Mtx/MAgHow4giOyQR7gLN9dynFURiuz5kzWlfBSa3wdicPv7EP3p4ccPjiPP44O9/QdCgd09enzvyiPvR8qzhwf3j8PXIg8NkuZDEL948PDh1Vf/kTt6/rQ/dVz8CfePnucWt9ALD98KObiWI4XeBMS/4StJpCCKgA6XLwYOVcAjG3dAr77jO/OFhTODzs/4yWLTC48Q8EPmFeE4OG6sM@S0HYN1ueUqVPTJqqSvBKjFsiCMme2csWKG9RzL0l3m9Psb4DnU8eikgZKwZWFLxKzPHNfqnZk9Y0N4hKc0yyp@Hx6REB4AkNG0S0YRQApCG8UwqtkMl7A61tRg0zFb6wkP9EKnaw6GMAafOUEEoaPrDH4fekF6I3pNbvaY8DzI71qIdT26EBN2Y6W8KO6L4gN9oterrlF8UfUylYoajz9xxbI4hmFZ9wbGwQxaLnsOPUl352lxIov3mdyODXBhxHLGqMB44wZI/GWt0drJafVSJp/969/68d/9ya8Pamozs5@RtncePXQm7G0xhcJExcs5rMQlQ9xhXwHGB8IxI/nXl5Fl0pa0cilfKme1UrpULuXyaiGfT6taGlTNYhl0jYxaUgulfFlNl3JlkFFyZQjNl4u@hK0EIrWyVQGwdhe/Zr5NCpc8BM2KL2iyNwk9yWJ6@D5logFpRAG12wkdUt8yazC8MjXDskUGEHXWZbH79/cz9@@L4l18wQ0h@xlR7OFLvpTJFO@KokEh@yWUt0SHpymhXUhxwl8ymbtA/ykHgJ9UEMUhvhwUcJ5OFE182d@7fx/z6eOLhukh2gkP4S9W8FKEaDa@gOBPAF6H0CDaHs8nR4ge4AtmiSH3ecg@hInixwE6GPKUR@MAHgQl3dsTxUP@sreHIftU7DxH9Gv4skeXKLrwAh1DFAfgGLjQJUWxA07sHqLYBVd3roMffjkere7bE10U55w8SCBRnFFsvXsiiu3AH7P51Mcmj9St0IvKS71LL2X8E0UtQBqjZcOXrCjmwpcclO3Bg0/14aRnDPg1d/mzCyV98CCrm7Ppwf3Oxx93BoOOO987@PgpBu3vPwBZZT51O4OOn7DThsuBVPsPNP1kNL96QakP2@2Kbq0M@lq7ndPtK0HtedtADCHVa8DMvwaY0ai9D0H7D9q7@qoFaQLYRs4wgmcHr7sjeN7VOzwouCiInrNOR6xi81eUZkJAbQJXlrE7ngCntdMjves6VXyf1VgmjQLNvFHItKoUwEagFWSqlxjeT@Bdx0ml5Pm8MatlWrVZrajxHU39hNicaXlTTG@MdtRyvrKh76haLjWroJ0Mpx9ncUndYQn1ztYblnic3NFAQxCbOzuS2FBbO5paqhSKL7amopis4H0nW6y8SWTiGcbwlmwUWzvFfCRFsZjSFa1SLIKcBjSZwHDfwZmediJxZugnySRiS/MOUAQqK5tTOc1qPzFLz2ocLzZPVmc1tcqtTbPMNWA9/LTBtDtxXA5yAOBmO5kK7mJIiGq5JAICipJIJkOmp4Brsd30s68fnxwff04CYd2fEnniGsi9qv7rxw/25cOj4A0/SiDfRznVceV95FpLIVxgDbyOQUORH8AQC9pe4IfnEV3Hkg9omx4Iu0FAYBdJ9g0Ey8cPluA8GzpnPGc051AlK5N212D4zQazx/RaHVx6jyUIK6Ynz2hwb9frtXZtRBYPoIhBqq8x@qDBAsyhx3EPjUxQ8nM8o@cHtGuZy2qnNovNAE67xiT15cjpvdRS3WoPP9Vwt3YXE1fb8OxUjZrhuo4rgq4tVvs7dm1qe3rfeGK4aD7l8GgTRA08uJfoMyO5yZoHGHsf9ZhLqe4ye4HZ4@kooUv1TnLZC6f7Qg8kTuLrQaHP6SxpuyaKl9V@jSVeQNTX8O5uskRPvpvcyVWBTndZOwlemZf9l32msUKuSnpIAmFBVyL6YLl1lqzVvwYPDvukUgFs/Io@AaiYGQA2exQAscfmZbVbs1hCYjOWJCLlqoNaA5Nf4G1bEsWWJDUuWkJdkj4T6tBfq/OYXvOmHfrKD8t0VC1TqM7ATy3mqkOoXv3FrOrWxlPXqFrw6s8S8mOzehWICrQDMG8uEu9@6RvJbSlf435VAnWBMkBbbtdmVRvthkLDqGVrEJBq5DJp0PDhVkzDmK8V0mohnU3n0lIRfWHAT@fT4AkaEAgeCSshMiamM7OMrKZVQ00nMi/N3stk@iQBAg0RjSXTE@fAno4Y@EBVYdukV3gCeVLalgWaWc9h@rZEjRVYRhULBlQfsrGZHiKop4ZuUYpkUmLZrYS1mcA4m8fT8UGjVakczMZfh6CE9HqnkCpmUm@SyWpiI1nzjNdCvSrUkb1Qqccb0HL9CVTmTUcNqGVwqUWt0mh0sIjFTDqbyULpzPbFYFusi610ZqOgQhVdMmIbjPON6JwiSjwLv3EbJXPLgKpTy1pVkGmCL1vSpLKS38pn@CQjTymMffaGlGSJphgcEU/E40UtHk/Gq7jAsSH689nA04ifxYG7xu@oOyIIY2JFLGsYYcEa6RRwJsAOxLFLAaVFlgPF91y4PL/crgtfEZ7h2c5t7QX@FV882jvCv6@AVxleSy8ePT96fnRfYAptGgXRs7pRlavtKrxIcn1XiFUYA07a9O1XKRuMfeh21NR2/QV/NvHAAsAVyBZ4g7Vom5hholbHPkXbCDssDmXQ3VFD07KthlaEsQ@4aRBV09QqWoSK4YEIua7QybdcMUsn34TY7ByQ3U6R/9fYfK6npGBe4A7bHaQ2@UmesriN6Qp@Or4at4mJTtunMYab3l9UT6snmfK2QMSNXdkdX92r7Q2e7lWZmC0WxerefhucYoLFqmLeB1rNPYg/jR/HD@PbybpYKpBveRfn0VdPXNRBujo5Uf3TRsVMW6zGWFvM@8f6IkeScuJ2uSngZvp47DzOYvFL@Fug@OJNcGKpADBOMtsvgB/GQnSSsSALrS2@YF71RFIz29BkdunYpsaPbbJYeHATF6H99aNsrsCS5WBx5yvx3Vgc11Aqnvd2cSLQh662xXqMZVTppBrbZmIpoMubzElVLBb8t7KY8wuY9LMAvRNbdHCg7msvNehMMdsJPEDXxHlAGOzzeVyyiCkvx94XWin76PDIvufejxzteoEIAAZ4Tq1aedHeOFGhE2XF7Ek6xnZjdLpBLEP@GvcAgp8wtfoCCc/E5/eOHok5JBZobeCVgEJxrCHT5sbFhoNrVCzcLPnW/uTrjI3j2RxuNqzFZrWcv1FfrdcldVtDM3pFVoEhs68WpMxFnTOFOgUUNAh590s/yM22S/CuZVR417R8SqvX1S2NJWPjd1/@PhpEOj/4dO8hi@PKxt/9yY@04t/9yb@i7X/xS1rt0LLFGMREp1ooxs7Px@fnl3DxsHysFbu266EFlamoWta27SqrKLq@VUzltF27qsT8AhTVZMyTYv4W12whLyUSqgJYbWVLmSSEXfgxtUwJ3oI1Px5dLEBFQQEOnpp5Td3d3oHy7WRzWnUD2psaHhNm4d@24ZVjQqz06OUFY/DSrfcGA1Mjl6KwyluJbb@VttlbXHF7K22wl7U67t1Q8XBxsCK1hYctcV02Xk8pW3EGKiarNy6rl60ULWmBov7CMLbs5hVqNDfwvM2y15YNf8aWR3@YKPDw4DV4M7ZeeWJiK6kovZ54vX9vGyxfhwazpSyOQLOtYKGK/0lSM/nul35D0wp/9ye/dtG@aH@ugZpeLhdULfazn21P7aln9Oo/AwA3GMMJVG2SttFqDTpCFZ1xa6ymnyp0yF1RiE1tVEd4/EBhRxWdgShnDmyjRwq7cIriJ1Vum9tj7CUo2hbaykiTOkP2z5JVQQjkfq6uuINummCwLTQh3GglhXPhqxgE0g0DlacqfHUBCjxGIM843bZnTd0xnVdKUDq1lWZ3IAnk8FW0dblBNj78oVFSq0zZup6Uo@wR1UhUZSPD89ByJozqwlchiW9n3ZqzsY7maDCmacNYLGMUwpMCeg3IuwV5WzxBm3wTVHoeIc04djyRDSqN8FWQzogKJghtzNyGCFXgX18FAkAZEj5gs8W2WTbJzs1Uqrowy3mJ5ybQcKgemMIQMBlC66HplSBxFeOBF6hS@GVfbBd@DYPMHPEMgHAYfNdFDZQxTE5vKAeTrZr3BgWwyC5cgorG7txZYFWrmb0koxIh/BNzjBONVA/2alwBWKDIftSriGmGBk@rgW/Y7IDiKUIXWp3ELZ1WI0mZiK@XggD/791osUVeqSoKqGIB/PrivaILJIPESHZeh122XWOqVkyyEPku4N4lpMggQaidN2cfydrnQeAlYPizWPDdLGBax9HJW7/dXrWFwkB3meJHi9AiHmcGvg0TbvMOmd/hJEgdpoKimBbF7psu6I20HSQwt5nIqklMtjBPSngQH9dyDA8Y5JP4oFQYm8FTR7ORfj4bZO6q60CFemPHJjuTZAcLT3dAiwAe5Zvo42hP7TP8yJ1fN5Q4ipFH5vmw5SPGZDfTQYNClBZ3Y3RcQz8JaJNmxkBm3VGPaWWWoIZGpgTtEFySEhHCHVA/kMYdyxgBSs8Mg04NehVFGYBIOu2QPcVHJrSr4X0TRiDbU@5xAitn5ompHKO1acnp4@FCbp0mhlIsdj@@8cO3XWg5zgmzzBODz8knlmz7eAwUMNAh0kDZxQ8IW8E9RVo2jfNAaprHgl8RHkXuLKUjaTcS8@T1Z1bdSLSxRi9ovDGhVizjVLcj9KXrQvBnHry5F1gHIxtX8C6HLNfw7QLV4mjxIzR4Jfh2zmpkYkvGtZ5xQoyJgX0wdApj1zhlOIcg4BgDTLMbWNrBXgyl/SoNANT3oGeh2dCJW0H7UICJ20t0oev5DN5mH7GsJmBEbrzNN7QGMLDqa8vQIQySYjm8SQ8qRqYFDuQr0DtHPQhDyyR@88P0QetGN5l0XTRvtuGDw0GH8qox3i2Cl3zkBXsHtmcq@gYEFgDDFZhsJMQUgE2JSZGDDtNfTc5bu0C8pMKuQ0ozhOCTGqCQqKAjy0G7kJGv0QkQcFf3@CdLfKOiZ2dnMlm6nbqmbHj4hTbPsXVLGQ9MEL0dZWKMxv63sM2uMg7gLlwS/zCjPB6Od2Yo3dbKd@b8KQh9r@bvy0rE@14cB8dT/ADZYERW8dAcnUcN6r5JHy/sJvxtYrz9aa30edD@Ktj@pFL8EoGA1gZgZul5upsGYOlO9yTdP@tV/YBT6pAAHGrRCDzR/rQbvIy8wGWO@2EMZ4J8NAzqWCe0Yg6QRD5hvsialzCIOQ9e/fexOYNEtnHG9lxXnycoPImxsQEn5iT2sDkM@xQCTjTnfs6NIZuzxry1lHwWJodBLdwv4qLJO@H8ZqDcMjaGz3j4DMJnPHy2yDTItjFrcZEMvS6xONjq0VJqEBPBzIM4l9yK9CKEIIM8DioV@WHM@ZLfJfy6NUod0Ju/QT3WgoYBbWIMBDcSSuNFs9Fs2Z5xttVKKQNo7CIRAmocQDdaRNOzXuhG6lun1tjxlrxsNJALo5KPN3p1h35r4G0FyxhWEDUMTi8TbZoORv7GFi4Q@AUGCCiHQSCKBnuThJmshqbYKRAaTkNc0Jgj1vCRaZH05Qf5fiAucdJzwkYBtSKA0D8sEqAJISzoOfx7nAF3@Mx1IE4QV6JPCI7Qtl68FQdKXukqnNdUqZIiWElSgCaQHcXV2tWiBOFQFY0rQZFiXvr1H0V/44PR70O/WI09NVg@YFSFaFfBTaggQvjdhajK6rVIvQIGypZuGS6MXAdcPvVHa8hmSwnUDJ4PFsE7MyfdYSJS@d0krx863SraYiVsCvNaDYo4r/FuyftFQFJO8DCZ5yebBw3BT88ZCMDIrExm@Mlm0WSzWo0zDjZbk@wsguSMkJzxJDz2bA2SLT8ZaE@HwfCC1dMC6RR3yYoAT@XDKIhBY5F5@qmB2w9eod1PXKTx81zwHGoFfhtCERvbWbe1MvdGBOkI07oCABviNQA9/mnvinCV4alS@BbyKE7KgEfxN78ZcF4BDYxYcJXbxk6EjYx0YBD4xRSNA9B3xVRDEFWaaMe/DP@J6cAz@KnXPTPLMdVlz0z6yt8/iGcLKRvpoBHpQ83kkCGjJvPc9o3KRmWOGNubgoIDUl3nzGGJFcI2@CtTP6nSsZyOMtJxGxF@8Jf7yuN5MtAfcKmK7Y6diT5xcrkKV5pManar8uc6gzmwHfxOWMQ@Psh6Pcfw7PgEKrXrDGzTM9IMTZeeGL7aYfhf7BCicrLvdDxB8De0cTUWQfN2haJuu23a5qTdTuA@0WQl3C1P20axecbjAuq/4IqkB/bkAz0aJ5zOK6M7Sd4OEz/24Cc7NrsniaOxH4gmPfYY8LAuyP8QOgQJhnnOQnMkQ/IoSncmCfqyydAZOQOQ@qaejHPNwhXwhwvYiJA@HhMuaaajSluJfPKDekmim9aTftKvfXBS9jUtoSfD9NoygCVipJl7lcZIWXdFdu212fFkQX7PPhzfZ1F8n92ML2nhV3HmqnmNB35Y1tnEAgJEXKCRvR0NLDrwrd41dJZQCb1Rrvp/u/v@vTZyZc@/8VMoNhncod22SSCJiZkYMInPIZALJDlZwngauw09MbbHbX54kszn3vvHvsDu//sI@yr3He5f@xRn61sldattY8jM2T372XxmcHdLKpVKpVJJKlVJgXuj2GYzvTYwrVHWms7udYg/3PgtorcY8fe30X9@B5ri9ft2n0/DXh2OSd5cwOI1z6EdI3PinKfsDQeyZ7q6mLW371kX5UVU3R2oEKTGsuDqwQc2DcwBLbujeAPZAL6D52EZN8X3bC5XlcQZOA2vXPV55fYu2m62g64/Dtp5ndO14JoWH9CCjeXV/RoOQcdCry9rvTzNXU6cStM4iC6ZKrewjO9eOc7tbCVZwph7eKecMWzcTj@kT4lmbPFVZbea1gFLSzlsx16F2P4cjAdjCbPQlbh@Wo7K/CM9CQ8ddxOE6CCzZ9lNqnXmic@DfNyke8wIcV4v3WR4QTcQ4Rtrug@/j0R3t5Q61ypUNb2cSQcYmt3j4bwet7jC8KQcRt2PJe9iunvznMVqAiwRYVvfN4VMQYaZTKuVtyHKl7k91u9NyQR843263i2zSnOGQI1LsqQbhbzcZv3CyWBl3KBfbDi9p18APAtGTWEo0zbsaelQuYpTLvyBpbXoL6SkExSLikJyjYaVK2OeKfuXb3GdrVvrbE3V2UrVGY@AdJVWpkwrVaXuBXTPvC7oBp3RLdIZSVg70888sU3/en1/iN2KL0vhUiV01dLVUoUE8lKwVKnnSSgvtZcq2/wQLVUO@eHzUuWv9JCMraWvSxUzLJBhSK/88BLftQjHe2upspV3vmVG/ucgMvV6S5W4TynPj/LKFCFSoN2kNeKIrdfXzRwNA5rYWKl0FTgmcrF84n0Yl/8v0X8SMoyDCSERe5yPOLNaVuXUpGHNGFIPTRsmWMWMkVzRs3l9f4fNzOIsqGaZ1nh2GQZPanhuKS2MBDGk8okG/RKCkJuV2Rgpaya7Jzq6duJQ7uR0/Uw9j/WBdp7TjynzSVIJx4nT5U1/pUFIB94PTxS@Dc8pdEx1jBHOZJ0ZaIGoPy/NaRT6Oo2L7n27h3ivO52JsC2YLNJLDNaS6aTD8eEcKhv0B2km4VRcdgjtMrwpJ4MS3DtRjKWCHpm3JPNn3TIIBnvwO/OaY5UDaikRhMTj0omMsnheYFmMpETWWZqqDD5CwZI5NMKD1meOwbetHzmfiBuX54rbpiFTVqpkyZUWk1TYg8exS38ktceL1zr8kH3f8tWUvMFeSx4ArJJxLSJf@9@hv/dFfzcKtSHCRAWzFOvZU@m0ej13lp3AvJtUO92BSHTVtjNTOYprSEhOqwNLM5/Ha1MqPkw@RMmXSmPoE9q@IVu8JriDbpNrC4EFLWF4lf74eYU@fl65nVDTGkn3yjNKi4eaNBxpeIxp0rT5uErDZ3UxUnh/2@9@dwcP0x1sdx7gcQOGEySXUT687LGVSzK2SWzLF4jUckWJIOfj0ribk48k7vnoNj62pQ/7zYPt/b3djzTpPn361NFz9DjBD6MWe63xPC6Q2WY9ng9mLFtWXATKwmE3tuOj8/5w9OBTLzslS0RYkzLgUy2G/fQYd7Qss@T5xNilcpLXoqiG9TkZBn5KKkHV8TFlh5quIyJIMMo/8jUQo94SvV1erTkcEqrZ7PkXQbPJ05cJ861nMXSNORF3/p57ULyMhhzOWuKZXWcy7AlEbe@rD69rR@rodV3tvNv6q/q4/059qO0dwQXE23ebu40tRf/X9w7rKpMyyEPsRywoia7bQStARF@1Uio9UQx5qz8Yi9zJbzny/dC/UK/7rQDHVC8i/@Llubx4vWC0IaXqtBwdYw8z5FifF@EI9hYcnJKWsVBu2nxBE5csFOU9pTXtBda8F/122AkpbwZr30EYROZOn@qG1IMkb821dleUJMShZNMhji8LC6xrKu5TfpzdEBhf7K9AYuSQwJVtT2nCxf@@m4JH9YM3hwreRLb297YbR439vUO1s39Ar28/NvZeET0bh0cHjc13SOKMb/a3GzuNrRp/EARKnoKbj18uo9FcFDxkZ6q0PuPk2xtQ98dv6V1vaPDq2uerqpFauuxB@oR@N/wtaC@tZy4jqC@4HstHBSq/WDt49Z7mfBX8ihNOcxTM9gfZdxHHRl0sqRdcGw2WDRpv63q40rRXKDt8HnExVgiPFKyz@488P7vKAGcjnnYYqOwWbFSw9y1eQngsG9BU0QOCDVDGYKWqOKzZ0pL7gkFuUG2tbh9eXKU2MSLULyj60piarGeYYtpWBkBxjaTRw35QeT3@QHxPH1Z0taOhZFCP4w@SQT2RD1BFG7AdUas6x@Vo/xLiWa3Jh18uBjt8LKyexh82fV7FPtM4Sb9xl/oqDgsJnyldDl4nuzwcYNePWmHIRSLOj8Bu3a4MjEBCipJMlKNEtm2jnFkSNh0cNWizNwnVjVTiBtgJ@Z1RpPJVx1NHMA4KeqGEDTzr@j0xgUpMd5j31DM4qKrqm/BhHG6PL@YM@syACPWZxiMut621wuC@5ajk5lSNvraR5JC3xgTtLgQ2pxD4I2AIUCG10mnxTMW3hwGm39GsnI/6xJHYt/3dzk/s3L5sBakC2mor/0v422@OJrKbWicZO0XGjrrot2BIaiUfZXb6QxrjLFY5QBmkYOu8PxiF0of5dAv4xImnOcqNiY1q@7m6kaoNdJissdfvWZWeEhffUuspMeV9amWOl7PzWHwlkauJ82kSFrs7oOOf9q8C6@zMxSHSdYDtF1KE@awcm5/jEWMi@mcmkR2/KwS8fVbd2N78VPj9ZxdRb0UsSNBpY3SI/4kxURcNDz7nY4PFIfQuPdJMtMLo8hSltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPQ1rXvWyux2libjz9HZeWJr/zx69fq1KqAMmkI5VH5/lEurnq2FTpcpkTpU1ALNlJyJKsz5svLsOM5fVLXFRCL8DfUg9yBOv2iViAWoSY1p1edkiy6JDMurtj@I7aYIuKJJ49LiDZ/VH8Kb9ZXd5wiolBibLImTci2jWQy45jmaXwfDUFbns@OJLf9wf3bC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7fC8u2wZFqyYN0f7O9zwMrk9ofAUtvd2wHLJDkNLeb0mDndxVxsTTu/xp@n@o7HHoHB3IsdlBioVdtlj4@ojU/0vBRwbDCJQnR4tF0/OFBZWZ9QWZJ7WDK0tRgE7AfqbWJtG/ZY2Hmx0hQvlmPlyXxJWbSZf/MG80zi3SIqtA7ianrEwiLxvN4Jb0Tq6ZmFVQi2vmeBaCiXxu6LkUHRsQb8jdaAhGzSaVYDMzObmZPJJ4xsI3BNN1d0Y9uGny2sZe5GoOPh2AZk2wT5Z7hZMrv/Poh@XDH1iIIFX1NocJs0aZpvaJ1wSBUPKKPnpXtwTreYLoWRvSjYOUM7GH6V0hr2n2coZiRRwkUXtsS6Vo41aqIfLxo1hw0SMQ34sPTUiWLRTAlGxPOXF3aHOsmkl09PQaRkIvTtS5srqPjJNz2FMTXiebIaK@T2WFtkbI4NlifYndWw12/P9BC20GuT4mGyKpK2c6sq/GOqklkiVZOh@czGmESCvLa6@vgu2JOtMMULfxa2zCGT8nN0MaD1fQIyGke8vU@c29hzTXrCAHNIJ6b1ZsBMFCRVZ8ackmo7T0Y2foSL7AsRMogrgGjCk7U66mYCt9nQZUayoXOWqTZYQzhuqIyaKep/m18dBPKd9T34/vpksCETTAe/wSr/TX8YBcmtPMtzjvUJHgfS34LhsMfZ5D7TBaDk@RrT3Mt2fNtODF6lVUjk8za7JR19O0nMbl2z18CV8PaihwDi2N1bn9zeK5TX7abuNHbr6hF7Ge2k9iKzw6xjyZ4HYW8eAiyDeV8C0wff4XsYVeh/wsE1IIlMfJsvz7Rx7sSNKUJa8zFHmtJmoVq2lid7vxO1/B58rbjZh5HKuj9QQd6Fre/vOLN21kvrqfKEXDTo5amUmy14WS5K37ChC0hpENKb@G5NWLipYSwlcb3mrA/7KBxsBTeye8aWk36x/Ky09jzDreu5I/fi@PmJ@6hVzSqafP3eRXQ5vG5/PuufX3VUVw1@Ob1pjX/7VanVJ@ox1bXygzh7Lq9Vi@xd9yn9faael5hzNYI/8lV5BLT2JNKvUksqWYevP1AOP/CiuYIbEhNcqh5dGC7EFbtR9eJ47aTaq5bWL457J@u45Ddaro6Wy8t5fPiBZlGSMXIyfzw6wZxq77oGvSsFh6ocUVZfDVF8NYS@vPGHYX@3tvcqtRsHBQBbYNrWmzfUJXj4AqzZcPfE6wXXeb1N5ipwbAYKUmaBbwWV4RKA95OxHdMOCTPqFZe02eiG/46dzELJuxyM@pxivGCCtdTX8GtmwVxjKvGOAmU5Do2vTNwvIDhJnjwOhuTrWKyoC2VR18q4O@lYII5RksVh9lM2izuFQFTf5To@yURe4LfOgUSX1OqvXEy9eKHwRqwWebyLB1MOf8gXJkoneMQBCP0M@LQBVbDmHvG1jww1H@9lPMgX3qMa8T0ZNpDPsKaIFJh/qy98v4nLvyACCOEXROfy9Ban1rxIkZS7g7y5ABdz6YU/jhlwrVI6ZQGNBWypr5oAZ0txphGq1WSi7wvXIKfQiv7pFhTK/DbVjDi/I9mZJHxOrd8i0JK7lJM28NNNiuWtYgVTzGS2SLFwJzWw00XLozcBDaux2gq6XUJaaLGQkAOPfL9X178c1x8do86TGHlJL0ylF1LpnqQLUkkujyb4JFPFzpTNfUnyfVPZJJs7VVdVsfLiUU@3PFJJkrzr8/JG3qjfDJPMG3FXClfGCS9SCQUr5acZvS8pD1JlYgaP048lXfP3iu75GMtU3pfp@vGb0R0UsPGstjWZ4FKvF3Z/zOhA6zoFbJYlaiolxTmEpjKDqqrvYGpxQhoc9vl52G5UEyjLZSNxeMxkN168zHpayfgxP4mG3GKcGlgzxohFJa5zmQl3wxcWqR5OfmCBYJhgNGVG7oYpPNaFxxZY5HpgqpVbkFMDnJo2OcSruBf5FX/MYE8jZ/LlZicuCOY30ni53ZwmEAvdB9nZZEpLE1wXkY@6UXNmkaTu8STE2UJiz9oFjusM5A52B9vgD2I5YQsKIymm6B6naEonGcqGfW/rQiR@y/y9@Cjzyicde9ANblQNywyfb2FlUhfcR0E0iuBtix0BRZeDQRenjqzwXfMVah2/YGUVxy0JRGtm9zINWPZIfhdP@kI6FfLUPiBfw0AkSYguz85wmQw3YPvXEK3YcQlHXqbWG8uGBo2ZxytyzTxQcL7BArgbntlISM/J6AGlo4HfCrwM6WgRaT8ZaWon1JFneT8d90bg1I2mtEom8y@XYevz1iuc5z4tlx6XLZJd6ePgkvf4SXLBiohkElbgl3G1/CSTsc6GW3I2XABAV@1ion9PvBlcBb1ekKnRjMEZI1Jao2B4FbS9TOYgiA@BAResjJNJ3MPuXw5bsrlDSpdPzIhbwpErx2HEYfjF/CzHxS0@K3MzOLRKTpupq6/CNghobpx0@jgd5gMLuAkQeqDQRTAiojxyVBolPnvWuLDucoGNKKIG/JxYZxMxGXr9UdiinuGdrEyXQMkxSFJZrz2BCdXX6vq4HOzNQgDXYxIKGATMUdI8HDL60Py7cFC6YeaM3Tc9UyTp1@exQsM9GIYkfRMCc69wMQt36uCj141Ddbi/c/ShdlBX9Pz2YP99Y7u@rTY/8hk3DsrZ/7F6vb9L0iU@TZdT8336kK0dUsksJ2Rqex9V/W9vD@qHh2r/QDXevN1tEDQCf1DbO2rUD13V2NvafbfNp@8EQe3tH6ndxpvGEWU72ne5VlMsk5RT@zvqTf1g6zW91jYbu42jj1zjTuNoD5XhVL@m3tYOjhpb73ZrB@rtu4O3@4d1hYZlthuHW7u1xpv6tkf1U52q/r6@d6QOX9d2dycauv9hr36g2EjAauVmnbCsbdISFjVxO7cbB/WtIzQoedoi4hGCu646fFvfauCh/rc6Nad28NHVQA/r//KOMlGi2q69qb2ixmXyd1CF@mXr3UEdHpRAicN3m4dHjaN3R3X1an9/m2l9WD9439iqH66rzO7@IRPs3WHdVQh6yVUTDKIWpdPz5rvDBtOtsXdEc8a7t7B3cKiTPxBhCMsaFd1mAsMMAq0lIu0ffARU0IE7wFUfXtfp@wFoytSqgQqwqNg6srNRhUTEI7uZaq/@arfxqr63VUfyPsB8aBzWHeqwxiEyNGCQ8ZFYhyp9x61GPxFe8kjMmjGc63J3qsaOqm2/bwBznZs44LChuYXJtvVa09yDB2RrEyXsY8/Av7A3VjrTn64C@Pyc3pGZvUcTe0za2t@u04ysnV1lk4R3NOs8m3ClZKfRTBMn0mvKZU07OL08a4a9Th93TONisvFxEZ25iOzkICjOp8ycAGd6f4UL5HLN5vtakxa6h82m496nZAqNu0robfB5uRzdRsS@wMobGz@VitD9RYpQGz/og0421MMBBHIK9X8Q0zf/InBUsdgOdDFc3gdgs3UUybHJOY5SSDTyZUdE80mq5J0Jfg81O3DBvAHvtZrYJ4VlJGfqR/Sn9zV5kcnB@kDSWba7ikUsYhmN8LfAVCOVsEsE/qM9EoQdrtKLguDzWb5kV4c1v3fW77fzjmPKcN4RrQPP8s4dxU@Ds4nihcnyjCwfO@uwEZFZd7MKE58/a5Ip3S/ekFuWx5/miH8cg434fMCuKVfFm9V60zL/gxSHRZKrtGsLXK/gTobO96b2t8YHrOZKK0/WJ76/jr/L2IK9ILwD04R3zOVO@Of1iWSgAca@OIgkofaQUSxaZYy9SZz5mjKeI9N12IblD83V5wHP60QSUmQv/a5dJ2bjYXhjY09y@NVB7c3mu50dEp3A9smz1adr65nY7dbfXPn9iHrYgS97HRvQPE56GidZo2SLFB8eKZb/9IT9mYGLRWSE33zTafwRfh5iu420JRMEGZobIbRVDyZ62QB0yCp2wPEgY/h15sjUDJBPNdVBay78G1bxfdKVmAe0MUt3zL12gz@AHQ9/M8TjBmkG0izGLo2Jc2l1wXIvu2NMRXlxw457kMXLGj4WN24xDXiri@1ncbuW3zRvW70YiSkjxit3O5ckJB5MYqGMXUVPRvZb9jOiN4DZexh9@ZvmN3r8qB3csbs7PxrVRodExp24JPapk81o3ehjDfkEcUzgVM3U9EJhl9/RSPHY09vJsWMQazQwKgjKAxvfNOD12I/IZJVsAftyyVFfhFPhvANw1jXH6nfi3FnN0VDWjf8Q/W68UiiBFTs5Eapdx3VkTJaPsR8LQ84Umf4UPRj@P5EmM@C/oBUnQU@oZTkBvBclGarQipavTJTw2hw0WKcbCTXtTx8TMN/sjjmPG6ZPb27kfg2RQPfO2Hz4yG4PO/kZBACTY2PDHr@xSdq5T0unl1lHF8c5Sa91McgrPVeYqWIKbmHtxGW1yzVnK3hxlCN7TVaFu1RUvZSF2ymPeloyTSzl1cMoK@Ac4/@j@Ig3QOIBz1x6Llark5xV0qPMyAHtasmacNqxxyRSS7/demr3SFkuMlOyX598GUIR6A3gM91ODujSV2Kem/a4yDOxOmIveHDTjmUyJh/tsu6UDTG7AeA8bPNmCGK@jK4xQXQFOrvqS6Cp/EM2FEElidVh4mcQ4tbxiLQ8rV7H2PPOJDg0xv5dTyIEBLKrZXJ44uBDY2hfl/fUG39MKHfv12xhseKjw74L20VUJtsSujzi27T6/SGpjj7aTTi64djx1Ae96RD0osuh9l9I81k41DsSRumnaqA2yeqdpxlxzc@oReEItxXaHvMHN@kigIWouCe5KaypPDGv4dENs@kY3iyXVf5FkvKCaMJuSZmIL9Sa@vpVcglBtcvQgCkYRvHigm02uR6cO8TD77o//Iy5HypQrx20Y8@kFkjeC5ROavTYx2NrJE0f9CPe0aCuwA5ITImybKTFhqo0Rz/V7KTtmrKJd0z4LuWWfH89MZMaaymqKGFcXTsx31qBOhNUWtGuQWNnoeWVVUZl1oLr262LMfYWmj62VtlPvVikVESJqD40qiOeRG7GTx/xpDf5qw8jjB76gjNurYICYeisOFedlnOMH2wKPoTBsG3viZIm0/YH2H7jpU@/x7xotg6127@WP4qCMa0AWsXwpsgwmvm/9M97za1@1z8L@6FP6zT41b8RiYfHMT@iw86G/euIQzdJPEorU3ucPIt/GXHDhvf4XHLdcs0VjYJB3jZTGA3HtXNxE8E75zACTOLNMn8PJn2kxWWerCaFMun7p2yPV3bWby37uDyrsJzoA4AWcBsTFhRyh3TEF5Osy6frUxlO52WwcDxVBeU7t1jspTB@TiTiY5gUxgaZKbMEuxFYmd2K8XH7xm2zD8IhHC0F2wECDUV5/uz6COJNUuRHWApUVPlZySoqpyg38EOIh/Ht5F55@k/GnhD4E@iXH8/illmMwCKuY7wtRbJe0V5GCRc2DwxZRrMkJikWnoU96/ohR/W4mYSaTh7fRg22/CGlSLvZm@JKjMg8LXwQYTDfJJHTHDuYVJbUksN@O6CC1Eb50u0MG9xlP8uDH4e4snMGwbSlIectpG8jVYuohCDJE@a1NsriU/nuEbOyct9emyBgdZbJmRWuO581mgvfQAllfsWxVn9Iwjg7QT1t6rEUjfqDpXtS71bZMdMz2yxatxznTkNgYbYqTZaP2kza6hiP4/XMJD4TTJOmGFuaEQ9h@crPMZtPEvGm2sR4qzbHd9DhNpoldlPxpBL3d1vGPibFK1j0mokmHlKMO5yUrsffj5vU8ObtEkTDlOVVkyVGEyKjOZZHC9QEmWIq3Z9CzH0a9wl6tIlyqLdNtLP751aiThrJGZenJinl5BL0hON2XNokuTTowPgCbuJEw42FVKxw3rhjPsorF07hZBgJAhBacVBI9qFkBzfprAk@4ugAnXwT1kJlSCJ62rAtHGKn/zHB2Cu/3tzRFg/NcaF8si6QbmJItKrgXPMgmfvm9HrcvGEoU6SgIT6DFHGLpmTT@f1b9WfbQvkIgpTmZG3pW3LRGEctEzb0x05q3kAHTqrSJVMjKj0QmiwaaCzQKuWsG8hyFdpfOBSOh3WDHka0gJDPefws6xJw571WiqmNIjftMbI4mtwy2hxV2JAiCUPJO8ivh6KourxwJQCBYEzlq2WCALemjD0OBdj1js15KUR1H1HBahnDkj6yV9TEznNGOoiqMzxZtXKUZuV4bsMozARCisXsPAkipLPMzpJAoYluJi5Wjqez25PkIIXY8L5QnLpC90qahnHPCQE5yHfJSSTKcVm5Jc3BnPhk1UklxvzNqc9LVmppMpXoE2N4XChPpj4rpVJT1a6spIumShI9HLvWVCKRwrERjqXCn/vHV1Nsl@exTai1yEhpGdo@G0HYaZVJ6zbvl0i94EvZRscw8Oyb4Wb51ZQQKymn7PMdsKslPjKA7/Y/3VpjmWow0bEC2C@dueySlwUha6xZTPVoFla6xtNe7KDArGn7HfX@aGcn5fb1dGwMjS6C4WqpVAITn9rO741tNbaSwn4xnbvYuex2i4PrvwzfnxZZ9gcBhwSomBV0QF1CgyLy@sMziQwBHCgrchf0RVas9S87HTsEA04o0XnUbZJTe0NQPAGFsdHL@yPeAGKQeoL9GQ1E@35W8ei79kXR1FDMMRSVhknwVdacnhF58KED@@z4pIqBQTAbayaat5zqxhfMIIhswp3F7oudL4l5cvZ10O32XfUBwZ/hKWDh22SBnR27QEmy4ISRb/deRuyP1lXBVdi17hUji83rAGcmJhNnwviFh2/8g@CsfjPIZ49/ytK0Qk1eRjOX4Z/aVdmzrKOdxd8DrPAhoX2v3Bf@IN9iOk1mpqlej@DkiTB6XHZnrn1SWRzeE9M0uzs3iDobXY@dNVDTHdYFjC977l5uyS3ZY@JmP92UO6BhSWBonOBz5X4lcNXsnycWr0adzv2kIocBkI79LokokVD@nEDkMwAegXr4ET3hRfuvBRrWOxMORUTBQbCOabmDAk0UyGQetqq/XudrtZpaHCwvq1ptkx4KBVXbrKltfNjcVNv0von3H6orq6vrInO3nS/0cdN8/KY2CQbvcC63zofb9EppVdwbg7U2unixWF101xeb1Rcb61HxuLaJa/309J//9l//89//W7GmX/4HXjb55finOJPnecXF1pfFH76t4/14@2Rp8fR4cXCydLYOLvs7ew3vN0YFPzEf9YanmZzMAtZXtiM162z2PqOLKhM88MIffibpUlG5VlTM6a@RRI5iGZtrBdb3APcoT2kJb4IOTC7lCYkcAR1jO556pxXAAI/mG6Ik4QI7UCkvZytm4x7uYOIM8alKTnviYZ31KsCdlsSTAu7i0oxVCHtR0MMO@BXrvNK8TMan33DU1Pxb/OlNdLbZv1GPPuXVo5J65KpH2Sz/lNee01dnsRjidq5ko@VANutSSnK0ADNDFYWs6PH6gWPtTJA7k1nkkD2AZNxUcGa5BefGqz@@LCMB16KzzAJimyrZIuFDJhTJfVnsfaNu@UI5vmVTV21YUWjqVQxXZp2oxP0LFciPxBAgqflCCFLpU5U46eMbyXgqmi@6rzMcTYgBg6wHr3Z43OMDzUWLPW3znFpLIcwRm8/LV8yN63IZmtFGitSfIMAHKrKcLPFNwqXcUkasvK1WcjPlFrbdPs18YuswDkbGNl0K/a4sJhBrbptwiz19r0UbcsvxisqG8fGKVVV20vZbZawiF5fdUTjQ1xW4dgyoL3Ft32QkoUcZkMARn/2V6RHGGwXGU9REt0iwrLFq99F0GQk9fTWdOtjx5OTIIkLxpzyN7a8TY9sp8i0Rww7CA4xUbMrX8cNupL2uDJnYZ/7wFNEB/Q4HVBvJuRnv5yFG7QTG/U6MtMeQ2eQ8Gc/UlNxg6J9d@K7K7fWPhv64QdMWaT6jludQC@GCCUhg8OmqZzXPICwt0l3CFImbwpZDCF7QHevwaNK32fjOCbrUDAXtdgWDIMVOTMnga6qvJuiYcPV3dIKN8pTwjk8jtYhlyQtLIw0pa1@b4WE2NXQypgZ77MQDJ5sRVOORaXhBF7rERHvBB78kybvwEaDrzupbgPoqwtpz1I/Z6Szo@anJadDNmIv@xXUl8yLGM4eiFGukjIbytJxEvANWpEf@lPYCIXOTcWeUWcjnFz5FOpxbzp5H2Ml3bItf9FUYB6DjAGZ8M0S964UiLCdmqCQGhqcabPlPEDpd/4zwG1/7Y7Dip1z@xwdF5/inT72TR/lPva@ffnMYEy2SzSxbUDl9mG0klh4rNDMW3dSrsUqLjKvBT710hk89JXdYLBIQIsX88U/Fk69FQuhTznEeFT/lhCCpLgMmxfn1FQG@OIVmLo1FMZdZcB45pvPzP5YdRXMr/6IP5YMjv4SFWVTyNj2tc4YdAsX3dH@9lCsnUfHZSunJSvkJrYTOgpvCMLjEfFuILk@DG1IlIixnaer59FuKG1KE@HYT@ev08YbaKWFN5O5JpC8paRGqhznXk4nZisp4whOUn6jM7lJxxcWJ8/g4fMSC31XEciYv@4IS00GL@/KYP6P@BerxI8i1ydshwpGwMhAbEd5CLQCyCb5yG4c6Zrgs8T0nT23BdysDoe4t5qzZotfvFbSy5nhL61CicWum@6z0rDQ5RqeGaGqELmplaumBKm/8@PQ//vv@r7lRbmOl@GFIv6Pcr7m1Zzl5pAd6e2zernIbuRfItvYtNy7SGpgen/7H/6TyG38hOEgZv6A/G6sG1to4t1GocpGvuY01eiivrFC9/@tf/5XasCgrNsRiXWy6ihFbNxTZ8nvMu5SuGmilLEuXErHCF7MAQywMaW1OLzCMull5VuJtupy2qrgKtOcrY4@ip3g2zBqxqZDsZBh7CtKMpEAVFRQEpDGh6CjLdsOYbYB5EzTVzw@9tYhWAD9rc464yth042EEk6FFWRZRB@alRlrPy8NG6cdsbN5RyRqbknWjQmJpp2Xts8frxA5v@8EobKWtJMxwvWj518GpBz70gvYlral6Ubf/y7B4RSx5UV55Vuxgc7/IdtzFAUMqDMbeb6QI6mBAtDBko1NXDakH@hdw4eVytCBS6HfiMykTT5K07EHQkj2sdExiyiJ3/Fw5HkZzvESVzvNfUuAROVMHgrRipX3qUcn9g4rKLscZJR@veR1g85aNY7ULjIJYww5YNnkZbgN2B017vNrwjC8hcSl4XZcsnt9uN32dls8sZE2oNDezcB50B9VsR9y7w3cqTkw0/UXNvBVKIcQOQqHAgg6wLoKRT0v0apa/YD2e1AA3KfqsNXYVl5C1o/PqVX27ylFX5lR9LVVfU49CS0jqiXnG8sam7GwiW6rYqhwGTRypzayYaotM0Oahxz/AIJJuaXRwLUE3h29AEtWS5mirMrvbXF4LE49cB3JnT7YWJXJ1JpdcfnRNDrlBDd0J9XpSGQkIeMGtwEKZ3g/lBkTVhBkNexnx5zeRbPx7aDDchn24ErXd1onzUZmWeleIfROO@C6lIhJov7K2DXZGZo8YdOxiKw5Bm8XGS9YBS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEymZln@q4peLwsh0dvVYCRdCHbKm88vjJ6trTZ88R5WxBt3Y2GBTysAoYnPsEgzXqPC2y8b1azS5l5RNCUE9XCeizwOIADmZd145j3D5fOw@q5ZIGVsoyrGsOoyHF9XYlg0wgDgMPMwKtUfLDbD7/Y@UYDTv51Ha@0v/E38Y/IDOccUfrC@mtfnibeKbKXIjDgSoLZnaKk38MDyqOTrHzBv3OAbxNBLB1FbaninbhAWJ0Puxfnp3b3OFp11ZHNGCI4OyXGiuoV8EocTBmYQVdVG84NKzbF1UD73i6BTDKxZQAnU@A0zDTfit9bWmK0bFEkxA8a@LGKo4QLdNRm52ZO3t9Vd/bnkQsZ4ehY7iebdlKyh17MoMDGcTqtZp7RNTV3i74KqmWSW7KqzILuBLylfk6vI@70i0EoraoYmQ16w2j/DyylJkXE9emSVHqR@A1A2a5dDcpzb1W0woQxAhCvZsUCzE3Ps@xSZbgZHcyxil4OVuxbETfhFHEDuZ0ZVlHW5RyJo4qsJC5BSD2bUpZaUipgh7lxzoHXpbeRjBHuRWNrQFthhyvVIOZOTnMBFvdRuIAG1HHDS3Q/sbelqu26/Rn58O2C0V5s/ZXtDsO8Xw7vmWNb7miGjumC2xvsWxzC5upX3FFiZilpB3GJghC@HYkKmKQeA2oN3Y07WVQH6fG9knCFWBXXyvhZndUDxI4euE9kAW9eI9dcfB1Hf5Wkc2raUkTu1TRw0K2uOYPbIsmC0mtMSQh5T1ArEyCiB21JNy@kDC8WKCz5u3rtYth7MbObJ5OsawsqEht3ykS2dM8eytl5rHFimaLlQr6cR5fMN/O5Y3ToNPXd9Fi5riDNx78Md4o3J85Cv9fMEf9n8MdjzV3PK5A9gh3xG7D@UYnh2Hvz@CY0zHPwc12eBZif6hjvaIRJdcCwAIPGOIOKSWWS2jbLeJE5WcnLE/ORzASWlnFxYA/1PgnuvFPKpC5/Lgd/L/a@MI/uPGruvGrFcw1M3peq3aWu/V/TIsTlTCf/jCze6HuSjbnj7Z0Tbd0rYLZdEY3/19vaeH/UEuf6pY@rcBjghw4iPv6@dwsmkjtcKvRSMwtvIx22pVHHPvZXOlg7dWuZmnx0OleRudVaOvqD@P/TOP/DNKInxCGDmcRsW1ovJaX5alclhfNknc5FC5ZSUukvcYzutVePWEl6xE9QYmQ5o2toV6okELuSmJy2uQl@mMifePJ5744i2zXwTJxcG4toGVFWHaSIS6arw6SubIWzyvb7ANZbR0d7C7/FyHDhf9Z30Ij5NG110G3a2YSewl2FHud0o2xmgPYh3rNkWIVTU5GdqRve8fssnC7VGPHFhPz4uxFghy14fyP1lIX0DesqNzYMiLaeLq8WVXBNNcsL@QLtV0yzW6ybvEf4tLnmkufV9SBXhjcRipfb/hpXkzWaSurq/PmACnl4QcDsORS/jmj6n8D)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/znphs)

Erg has `#` line comments and nesting `#[..]#` block comments, so it is mixed with Nim and Lily.

Although in the current dev version of Erg it is possible to add code right after block comment like this: `#[]#print!0`,
[it will likely change](https://github.com/erg-lang/erg/pull/313#issuecomment-1364982652), so I didn't want to rely on that.
This means that Nim/Lily/Erg code requires a newline, so it was moved to the middle of the polyglot.

Unfortunately, this also means that Python2/CoffeeScript/Elixir string had to be changed from `"""` to `'''`.
Now we are back to the situation when Python2 and Python3/Coconut use the same string to hide the bulk of the polyglot.
Tcl code was moved to line 21. `'` in `#'  \` is needed for fish 3.5.0, but not fish 3.0.0 (on TIO).
Space in `'#{' #` on line 607 is for fish.

Lily/Nim/Erg code:

```py
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
```

Lily is separated by its non-nesting block comment as before, except now a multiline string is needed to hide part of Nim/Erg code.

Erg is separated from Nim with `"""\"""`. Nim treats `\` literally in `"""` strings, unlike Erg.
In Erg `let d="..."` defines function named `let` with one argument that returns a string.
Note: `var` breaks Grass. `d` and single `"` are for Pyth. `#` in `#\` is for Lily.

Comment: Python 3 seems to output `5`, what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena To test locally: Copy the text from TIO link input field. Save it as UTF-8 without BOM with UNIX line endings. Replace BELs with CRs: `tr '\a' '\r' < poly.txt > poly.py`. Or you can use the test driver to test only Python 3 - specify `1 0` as first argument.

Answer (score 1):

## 382. ><> ([fishr](https://github.com/noirotm/fishr)), 16530 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 |/183nnn;/283nnn; 
_|/1000 |/01-2%+?/123nnn; 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0-<?MLot ~7+<p>3:s4o 8d=5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1997*.; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6KxLkp7KhU0c1@ntpXycT12LAz457cvDZhUTChvaSXP7GVfQgPOq9Tmyi3tdNOvQOYS8u2IZ/0Bw8xODoun@0HtVDmvbUwLPx/Ms3k9omJFOrqfky28GPSlWYmqE08Tt5Za6FL0iswTbP/WPjlYp6yTZqTKyIzD@4HyrV5oqhATCqtIVCMelEZZsT8NkMDp0z@sYJu2A0VwbCuZrPgE1Wouo3qv6xfMjT5vnTw6cHz4/3jl88b2Ral/6x/aAUtg2pBcpB7mR7IhTexxvw4FxNPKmLsCA5@v4KzrF5QbkYftNpuWi1paItCiXuYJzNc9tWFNJcoEiXkD9J5KmRL44k4MRhByWmCvKVVlS4EgHShQB1xEGLlCZUWoVlViU81oGf3LR9/6ufQCNf/EReBT@Shwn7mr2hJQ4cp@en6Bns9itI8cHe4aMXzw5YkMFFqzkze5NhrZznit@5NhWop75JWzlrLO5HiUNd1WrxB3FATFyOswrpmiCl69DQIViAHdRS4cfeYolNgg8YjIeVovznbyiXcRlPJSQhbDzIVByShTZPDWVjY4MdQyNh958dfnLwjGH@D@6TM6IIQbBjPOj@Zz/u8c@WBIqogs8DuiNi/kiRjxBVdhFogFgoqUCcU98dr/9IIH0mhFRBhN8nCT@wJAj0@Rpot2ekQ/KKfsEkqfziHzX01T8GCVETCj51gAtgqMrR9dip6ZmoiALz0EfNisuNHffMkTZRme3hFxDxO4s6fUMHsj61J1x7ma/DKAYtTQ5pTpptUmb5F3fESMD49gY09o4BcgHzbBO4zEmFvYaWiItMFa6oRJLq8WtRAtAVMknIS0YCXlPF6ClNV3n/a/9EGVQZmCdg/o5vnmXuge1XfFsfzL/KzS8VbGjXVTcu8hLNEKpb9UvAMxLiH3Ef@fCjzZXDLBCHGiYDwsrMEVTTKWEdg/MU@FMCeryAk2h8ApUGzQ1qzFcKw9Mz3FYC9b1WFAWbFMqqMh3JMWZ8f@wVva@FfCGnKpBJ6TQASB9qGODBfw4wmaxANxFOzXHtFcg/29vbTMQJK6NWqPKaVTbtl1nxVZjRTQgrnA0xcw0GcSDKIgb41f1oMPqk1CRGReoVV@NIuHoODEvkj8MX2m0fESJLALI4jgzU/D/Db4ROgI3z9Rd38KuakY/4bPqAJBXGJDIlRcFXp/LEmUDzgU66@EwXV6eC@8P5EIiKQT3@5VxSG4ztUb7esxZaAIKvBfl9TUYawEFlM1dH02jdip8iiOcIoiKuar6Nl6w5adothbdNBs30hysasw3mX1YGa9osL/fedaWxiasqXxFZbPe57eDM3AMoDEtoipZV1EJyUaRcbmWR/BL5yUBxUDPVBSQHZApIRtcwXztjb2//4PDjo6fPrylGpZDxq8GA7te3U01JTjdaoSEeLdZyldx7oDx/fO9BUBGLTBci1BgIv18S9aaSLCbcEeTiANfVoq3K4dXSrc/xp1zFw9X8ZrWbskaRruVDzXyJdOkQhfSAjkJeTVwrrcJWPn9TlhbwlAjofX6O/VpWE8nzy0YL2GI7Fr/eElZ0hJcxeQs7AZia3tamgo39euGwYOE3rY/xa4FetC9mV/dFcTOLevdQjcbEOVloJvQdIh6R8gbJAIkUZCUIurb3HXEmfaE/U@Pf3OYK@6LqyCIZLmRuwngE1HHw@W6kIgvtv77i26HuDS2zIwRq4LgC3EBPZ6j7lqtwSyQF/xsyPOGE/0HvWWUm047JRBKpHcFKs5t06QbwkgJ0aOTunk69IXvqjPk3BWhnzH0jMD1zgPzen/KZNIN9PB1BuD69nhm0SgmUW4LIgMl4mFXOSwGV8FXpzlKorBjSa6BCXb/g8qiXT8yS8tCY9cwB0PZEMg0U7Y6qtliobhcLTep17bhIdbaohRu74keonSCK9i@lc3m2yIDe0GXT7hmzRPwsnqy0IH10j599ehpPiqvaEul@9pUh964qgQ6zX1RvpiT6xO@dgYblVdSiXL5OJcDtKmCujDD4oFm5LA89gT5QWUPO/fnEfQRGYCMS/ZE@ZompzRU5yoysiWbCTpOGO6nOlcTaLJUigQpe5CEzitknEx@/E7o9Zwmlht8wBVfP7uHrrTlmDVWWW2CmRJJsEz80uA8cF6o2TQogBEOUCoGtYRMCMQNyxDuJzBs4xEF/CAsvUoe5wpu@u0aLOQ7ihErN6ndZ5MORy5yjWC5X/ApdpoplBq3vOjmUFQB7jc4FfD1g19fxBDgD8VcWYgtCfp3ixSjdGM/IQ185FGQnFlHsHOiMYgBroXa5O3TxThzY0FeAP6hUXhw/aJeSishCJVMD1@zhYiP/NkEo4vlfk4JuqiwFjVe5RPcRRkN1nm2uxQq1Sj6gDiNeIamxKBp8lciBsOwt2qaq3tjq/Yh@LUDIHA4A/mHcdgAOVbAGs5Ar/FYT@5/9LIbMRmJTVU/a7mkqns9U4aFW8yzP7mw2JWmzkantbuogRU3ezJogkytbufunxrDfOxwoTVFkWZZTlK3z8/P4g62n5ss8K0g9Uyu8mc0vs4Xsm9llVi29ORmrhYb8ZtYSS7X0SYs9ffrZu/a7pDg7nb8Rmwkttn90Iao5FPljlTI73ylkYydlED8hXcZO2Fu4TvoM/2R@24uYdTR3@iDCxkUWazYB46pYFBWlEW/Bn8T9V3Bxwb9Rl@vyTuvdu2RD1yezOTNNc@z1enA7Q@AgteRzBvLyXaD0PILCmvQmCQqv0ax/fT4hz9hszxgMpgd6XcNz2vJuuzo3pw8mjz//NLhe4PX2WSTaW//LxqlUQpIaK@YpKm09H8NvJP/ZTzYu0@dP29t/9s2RYmzg6whf37l8jObnav7Oxsade/dyubSmadz89POnv7i3t5e7n84/beR3clJmY/tP/2RjQ9O2NWWj5XlqK944OflM1DI5Uf6zH8XbT59@3fPq2f/zG@/qKj6K8DhlRaATcGWZCkZ8luBWkcf60Cv2NgatXI3N6deOBe7nG0yt7xT/y/eO3sQmsbqmfOrCexJ7EyuUYtwIBrBlA9tprB7bxmCFy9hcqdVqYCz@l38L8esfAxz0mW/Do54PYBXmsbpUoygXsXoBDKqmQbr/9ze@EckhJxM1YuOCa5c14BJzRU3cacG1Rde2gMo7pYyiBOHsyXBiOEwt3VXvosUEC7xsA7@CYEyaMfxKPDvaZexZI5VKteS2BJf8kiaJFFXVmqp6F8iBdGerVpO2GFdPms3m76KK9SRNaQ0cGDGNu5/@Q1yxVY7VnxvcMyFW2Nh9db9ehzJl69mteoouvyNRnyqWRMfZFVmavYqDCNJovXrEuE7lupgpaWI6nd5tk32GuJJmYUvCiz9jsdAFuyy76rYUBYL4rrEvHy52gNef/29//v0//x79vk/3f0DtpnbP7CtbEOgUukQdrt1KpVuvi3VXPG@ivQ7tKFMpVUpK@7KZ2AIK1HrG1MxHF/F8Nv6cf8FdZayZpNhwUbJ1P3m012ML5zp3qUfdfA8emByYXwoyLGGNzCHWroWDodXfBy41TustCRmimtRQC/mWxGPVg6vMGrtQTaJWLIutupbXjthue8YvNtz0mBMDybAQ4NHPb31Rtnros7DVo06xehCtvgjzZcOF@RVijYbSMmhACNzY7kZlo1QpVDSlXV9/QdOMWimoYRhPvdhpLLw4ZmMLhMbCpnnVLaiK0MKCFsy@TDiorA@Z7KZayhZUseqbtDYTq9BItKykDdpiRhXD3obz@3BtwI/@cIVWfG6Qi@9MQa5fG6yibmlZJX@ncKDh@HrLFc2rAOME63Y6nbfdDnAdut7Ru7o60af6TJ/rk860M@tMutMuwy6zPKOfdfJOyZmxGf1lKZbNq5uxu9So3zU22DNOhVosFVzN1K3XC1lu@0YyOHhLkjOLCbF/gKuuairbgvEpAw9gysgIMjP@VFVgMWC0zlvvthrvtqCD1lPbRBxbdcnPJbzk9m4rJV1eNsBcrfr/7XporNLFTVC41mUqtf2yDtzHy3ojBSBf@iBliRFQuV1vbZNPmJifmu@93QL@RUptN7Zrzj7dMnUQqQUQt5dyububksG0CzHrmyDApjYlaQOHxIY/REDQVj0VFAaTTgCTcH7@IXc858QLzu4KLxDzoA9fbl/WLxvbl5fb2/Dfpuel/wbXy@1rf3otrjVhFv4tJCzNhlJvKk2fVLTALit1dJGVJhjq8IZwjaxWajXQAJfc@m/zL6cXz9AFs9ySIddCbIttxVDTZja2JcRevf/if8G7@f6L30dukcHPqAixc@zUyhbKmmUucsKD2Y9t9phfNpjxDqzogg6P6@ho84eNy1GK8kpmFT7jn1BLhaSMw2/b6bdReYfMXkHQa5SPiVqpILZT6lxjsW2xUCRi9wvXrng8/o9eaeVinE/ToPaJV57nPY7kcpFPCFzVMqqkXtT5Bxb4t3B@YdX1j35h3SXELsrMqAB@EowjRohBO4opiiTBcFXfHuHxBFwokVAmPa19Jr3Yk3ASRZ/QMliXTxDUDg9q5XKdr/FsPqXOs3V/C54q/A82oBis2YewzX6tOwL2t9nP5rUmauOPSZ03@Hv0Fn/suIu/Z2/wx47f4u/ZBH/scQd/x2/wt9fB3/EIf/fe4O/xW/y9GOCv@ZVsVq2Km@eEmZRaVi83ZyJhqBrbqTe/MnHnFcuwG2av5X9oKpsrs2Ss@RVj1jXGkwp37Md/@t1vfjNeq8WlOH2@J6c6LlOTMYYB8RukjCWrUBNqRoUSevHqbvwrDRLR8@VWA4O0wFeI1dimuqlmrEw3o3bUDhhMlnFZZpgZqj2VRJmMwTLzzJxlRo7aA5MBvwyYzEyfZQYsY2dsCAa@YJq0MxM09eE1gF8fALnwM3FDbkfNdBkkZCFTRx8HVdsYM3PRbgoNFmfiKwNkUVmVM3LBbOEnlRriq1dNZaullUtMxmYntxuvmvGW2BRRzb5WzrHO3NhovhJh6M6IvHmiC4t5Hgi41ZjSbCock4AkQvTlZbt98OR@u63gMNV87Bwt/kdHo6j1xv/oyHl85Iwc@B8dHUHnMuqp3RTQ8d3dGtB1/7UTq1d3mhUaFoKhIaZs7zTrWQnNhRQQfQ3dUl/yWkCEd32jKcTPQMA4A9mkmgAJ5ax6Wq2ekeFTbgVDG83oGP7PfIP/JgjVUL45g@uUwJINjWefNkMTNyifnoHTpwzksvAPAmDU@l/hb/639X/8giVZotFKJs4vtxN0JfGXTJ5fnl/6z3oykfAtiW34oQPYMcr5ZR2NFOgcTI1EspW8vORu8EwktznAOiSzXae4i3AwcMTCJClZ/kj8131D0v7VjFeBL@aydz5D/SgmVpm@2HfTbM4ymWS1E3xBBFeR9Qva3JCs0ucjNzsNtfWnP6KvxOwkKVA@V62qW4xbtJxWreYCW7FUrZYCy2YiUb5@1TM7agHkk1wumaxWwbITgM2AFeI22LsUq7EmPFt37/JEStrFRQAzmyukMrjfqVoNUspDsoand32afH54RB9YAVKTj@GXjTgpSWTo80z4CcC4WBHv3k30DNz13dvZS969q5UzFxehy3gMTuqSU7vdM912G92zFxdiW6R9MuU82DOliws1U06p8aTjJp7gtyMhqYSksjtanVItA6XXckXw9jOQ394u5Or1Qg5cCqV4EtfcOYmH/MbFeFWMnVMZ1FKRU0Cxis7R/UPQl3GcYOeXMapQlssnE0BIk8AlXsbw5yLN5SNSPp8EzFyKPKRaLvOgSZYrJEqpsv@rbYDUDmwQ/yEvl03ltopbu8AT48@brbqQJlfPjZp6WTs3Kjjrflnt@l/hRiUlxt272TKgqJSpNoV2@/7e8V67XYOxDFkpeKAjUXcBdbe48Up1l@pVLeUZVCB3lOIwJLASYFnRtvJqCbEimH1UOgQ4ELj4tME2BI3e@BDKHFUb4AjyDaTWg4v1WIcN8GIDlOaYySy6mMW4Pz273TCQwy/fN7RSXBL4AhcjvAS/22V5m4RR@@mjvf2D47S2LbGY9mBvP609f3EvpqI1v7CTdxbtzw727h@9gAhPHx3sPT/46PCTgxdPwd1jZ4sroPL@c/GOmlbYz9inwmv3rW4YujE1jPbZdHr2hr02zbYJtWdNoVDOwGWe0YayjPVFuapwd01Pf/1ad8d0sfc//Pb7H/5373/nu@9/59vvf@f7P/3i@9@G@8dwf5e/v/tvynl8/vSLf/a773/7d8DxP8D9R3D/5Kdf/MY3@E32P4b7P0Xc/ti/I@H4LQCsX/npF9/70U@/@NUfwP0v/fsH1@9f@8nq@/vfWn9jvO/97s1hvvtv4f49DisI@93f5m74vhb@t3m4X/3B@3/x7/j/T/0fGn/n/b/4Y3z4ln/6gz/9T@@/@e81rfSn//r9t773/lvffP@t77z/1j/W3v/Gv1Yz0cfvvv/@H/zVH/7eX/3h/0j/H9Pz9z7k//4H//Qv/te/@N//4g/9@ydw/zsw/eQv/j10lb/9gx/i/3t/8Ld/9EP8/8//6m//4Nf/9lf@JzL8Jjf8P//y3/DnX//af/yb3/rOX/3kG3/z6z/5m9/8g7/6P371//qN//jX//3v//U/@SY6/uZP/uqPfuUvv/ntv/zWP//Lb36x5vntG59ffID7F/8ALh@ezw@B8yHl@rIuX/xc@fn7YGORCrQTaN2//P43fgka@L9g7P23f4zn@eBe8/@xplKYH3Pb/wcM2vUyo08GTHD/@vtvfxdR9D8AiuAf4us7oWXJh1u@s7AAWn9rRaRf/ukX//xHZIsZlTot4@BgXdJKqS0QaLbKZX/A9ld4IMovLUMLAfgpfQcp1JLfd5C2vf/hN97/6B@//@Fvvv/hr@BoLeXK6b20pN6yPAYB8x8QDgMWPiQcBvwM00/R1JuU@gxs7DPf87PPPhPaFwoeHN29ANfPyIlfjHvhwVLfK/BDdzxpyi5YxKyopaxt21VF42/me2UYJiBpd1I7iqotvDY5hEXOGGu8etXCBVpww9yliDfZCnilfJbNUn7GZ4yvA6E7BJptkXGGT3JF75mAj8V/YZwJLEWTw3yJIrUwksGP5yfBjUIekknNwtUnYt4Y5562uAstLFO6uTLDEsxmqRlIxWCAFFLgdQ/481othRFrPD9g5VmrlxhlJZWqQbkxNo@TbpcQxOweQYGYtdQz1t6qzXjEFMKrB@hICej0TFQ1MVWq3YcEa7P7DGEhcAL76lWtXqrN6gjuHcdHapa6R3lCYLXUrP4O7DWCCfGE2P13kJVSLZWqlzBBLCSvnnSbV1KeCkdlT7GUXwfwxvMBO7uM3RHVkshXFTYQYTw0PlOL0BgQgoN/M7XlF4f@gZHuLUL4BiXlp8K4/w7xrjucncUAAFeSZFlmcOOC/Q7bBe8ZB5WiZOGV4hBS1CKoBYQODCeMUkKK6jdFFkg/Vtv60hcCw8Jsbm4KsbqYFY9kQp2iMPekQoclcP8gyhsVJhbKIjobdHIkyAvEr1L6m3FciYszDpjdSfF7d3eL3YFi0nvhJjAplXVyToxD2U6lRA3g152U8BLkFAHaKQG6EORZjVb@UkI6zZhci6EfOzo68jNBDi9rQgqauZZV0Y7rT9PpNAYxZDktp9P@W6Y3Oci@QSZf/y1vInLpa@tM03JVEKeAJIATi8o@KsjE6Pju3TuoFdqQVTkEaZT5e7O0XIk8wYHr17GseXDESMuVBS6qM7WQYyxBs7JwJRmepUlAQ0oKfCM/z0ZwJeJaqRSnkIB/ObEVbNYrqNQgcFI2VsesBheXEkv5ZOC5f8T2jx4/PnhyPG61mGDQ9@ON9th1uobnJdBv78l9fohDKxeSsUYDQR9XNCQxwkElQ@T68P6zw@cVxovtV0KCMlalpVi/oGVViI3Hn27H/M1KIn4C0RGf47OyKFtCK2chaqwuxLoGyh64xo4ycZVVhcfe4J4zAzE/LYpptYCyXxJXFCEfv@hMGSro5dp8oFfh0Q55e5swINTPJVrvQCPUV0Go1/1tfkwV6s8PjiHC8RFTtYws1D9jMxkTlC6FulWzDHswGW7ifjmxmREjZdpsZNL407JZeKq5QlrNF1sbG9a5hGk2qdrOcePjJVjPJSzGV@FiwlcF9lVwggvSwN2MzN9KenhU9ffzoSq8BN/UJ6p56GhJAWe/OThhHL2q0L6XV4@E2Mbnn09YvQ4it3T4QIgBvRiyYEubZPbkoUzV3Ju6BvkOGOuZn5j4bUu5Z3pjS59D5wFsxC4vL/sA6fAB0@oaWXmMHj4vu@TSAfPlTBdidqVSe6fmioJ2Uqm8y2qaAA7CloJ75jagAdDWgy2F/6oeJJLNlhSgVaoowiubzQo4nSwIFUNgtL3kXaZWk3gbzOZU2l0i4OdS9FlNCy8/7OzOImw2w8OiD3iwwcRlmcCvyP18W0EgGyANN9TRx7mrfvfM3L2bxXmNbC4TTmBQidkl1M1mNpdFjOOBpVYsV/RXVkRRbMUEy5iwXg3MsSY8@BydpsZEhjYkG9lSRog1Yg3h/@@Xv3i0Pa5nM@q2MgajDsbctqKDsQPG/LbSAaMJxvK2YoJxWs@qmW1lWheYsM216DJU0lMTJ8YMlXZzN7HuGVZfxnNMNZES0MRtXyt9PYhY79V6TneKW0iqPdm0bcPFI/U8Qi4nVh0b9TvWUNMLKSFgieS5MKid0cF/wagNZFQZ5Nq6JfTkjtOby95kbuGJIMtxa3HgLOOBxwK6ASwMzqPtZLO5SoO15LEz3hG0fDHVUDMw9uCtltJaesPYKRYrPblrGbq7k6/kS@keHjbyV9R28pnKQP7s8aOHk8n4mUEnkHZyZYiASvZQHdZOqZLPtxoNUUw1KJkWflCc0zVpYwOIgaH3JHjjepsnaaUWRO6Zbq0Wj@9kVU1SK9lM6VJYIA5xjiWsCxg1hSVLI97PfdJRsR0bqFQlrafNc8JCpd/vX26dpxYWQT@XuA3wcynp6c55aK1KkXAVNk1L5sITXPQ@oPvcX0qsiFq@JFYb1YW9WBCrrUthd2T0TB0PHjUz59djFYCac6gxSKjJhMuK6ziTSsfoO66xCJhVC0FAnqHrAXLiZZhcM4Mpnl9PrhAJNDu/DiWXFy/DWEG2hMtLwDtHNqDdV5Fcpw26DbWcax0A7YLmsx1oT8ZgsZcvhdjWs0@y9TpU9XmuqOXyubyWLRTyRQ0GqnKukC9BZ8sUMnlNAyi5cqlcvIR2rSjvYvRxRLZ/HrT3Cn0eIqFXuH7TRosl3z0xrfNSVuL5SCSrl5exd0LszrNPNBhZ114JGK0/0aR6LZsvgymLJi0LGWaCpklaVsqqkprF/y0GDf8fHl6Dv4ZPiJXVhGNUevQExlvgEWz2CJWnTBx27ODnswbsntFdE2J/qNPu6X3X8by/R5h7un3Cve6bXNNw6PVQx28IeiNzMlwT4sV4hPqSDPcfDMLBqAMZRHLIA9yDh2s5zqoARfbi6ZpSPg51@wMyuHJ/CP7s8KOHx5H38cHe/kOhwO4dPbl/5ZX3A@XZo4MHx6G1yH2DqPkQxC8ePHp01eq/ckcvnvWnjou38ODoRW7xCJ3wcK6Qg2s5UOhMQPwHWokjBVYEZLh8MTCoAh7puAty9V3fmC8sjBk0fspPHpteeMSAH0KvCMfBcWSdIaXtGKzL1WKhoE8qK30hQC2WBWHMbOeMFTOs51iW7jKn398Ax6GORysN5IQtC1siJn3muFbvzOwZG8JjPMVZVvHj85gJ4SEAGU27pHEBuCBUgAyjms1wiatjTQ02HbO1jvBCJzS65mAIY/CZEwQQOrrO4P6yF8Q3otfkZocJT4PcrvlY14MLMWE3VsqL4r4oPtQner3qGsWXVS9Tqajx@FNXLItjGJZ1b2AczKDlshfQk3R3nhYnsviAye3YABdOLGeMAow3bgDHX9YarZ2cdlEvZfLZv/6tH//dn/z6oKbiXFIzs5@RtnceP3Im7F0xhRxFxcs5rNSr5StA9oA1ZsT9@hyyTLKSVi7lS@WsVkqXyqVcXi3k82lVS4OgWSyDpJFRS2qhlC@r6VKuDBxKrgy@@XLR56@VgKFWtioA1u7ih9K3SdyShyBX8eVO9jahJ1lMD@1TJhoQRxRQtp3QEfYtswaDK1MzLFtkAFFnXRZ78GA/8@CBKN5DC24X2c@IYg8t@VImU7wnigb57JeQ2xIdHqeEKifFCbdkMvcA@1MOAL/WIIpDtBwUcBZPFE207O89eIDp9NGiYXwIdsJ9uMUKLEUIZqMF2H4C8CaEBsH2eDo5yugBWjBJ9HnAffbBTxQ/CrKDPs94MA7gYVDSvT1RPOSWvT302adi53lGv4aWPbpE0QULdAtRHIBh4EKHFMUOGLFziGIXTN25Dm74UXpU6G9PdFGcc/QggkRxRqH17okotgN3TOYTPzd5xG6FLCov9S5ZyvgTRS3INAbLhpasKOZCSw7K9vDhJ/pw0jMG/Jq7/N2Fkj58mNXN2fTgQeejjzqDQced7x189Ay99vcfAqcyn7qdQceP2GnD5UCs/YeafjKaX72g1IftdkW3Vnp9rd3O6fYVr/a8bWAOIdYbyJl/DTChUXsfvPYftnf1VcvVBLCNdGEE7w5e90bwvqd3uFdwkRe9Z52OWMXmryjNhICyBK47Y3c8ATprp0d613WqaJ/VWCaN7My8Uci0quTBRiATZKqX6N9P4FPHKaXk@bwxq2VatVmtqPH9Tv2E2JxpeVNMb4x21HK@sqHvqFouNaugFg2nH2dxSd1hCfXu1luWeJLc0UA@EJs7O5LYUFs7mlqqFIovt6aimKzgcydbrLxNZOIZxvCRbBRbO8V8JEaxmNIVrVIsApcGOJnAYN/BeZ52InFm6CfJJOaWZh2gCFRWNqdymtV@Ypae1Xi@2DxZndXUKldkzTLXgPXwqwnT7sRxOcgBgJvtZCq4xyEhquWSCBlQlEQyGRI9BUyLzaiffv345Pj4M2IH6/6EyFPXQOpV9a0fPdyXD48CG37vQH6AXKrjyvtItZZ8OLsaOB2DfCI/hAEWZL3ADU8ruo4lH9AmPmB1A49A5ZLs6x6Wjx8uwXk@dM54yqjsoUoKLO2uwfBzEGaP6bU6mPQeS1CumJ48o6G9Xa/X2rUR6UOAIgaxvsboWwkLMIcez3uogoKin@MJPt@jXctcVju1WWwGcNo1JqmvRk7vlZbqVnv4FYh7tXsYudqGd6dq1AzXdVwRJG2x2t@xa1Pb0/vGU8NF5SqHR5vAaOCxvkSfGclN1jzA0PsoxVxKdZfZi5w9mY4SulTvJJedcLIvdEDkJL4eFPqcTpq2a6J4We3XWOIlBH0DdneTJXryveROrgp4usfaSXDKvOq/6jONFXJVkkISCAu6EuEHy62zZK3@NXhx2CeVCuTGr@gTgIqJAWCzRx4QemxeVrs1iyUkNmNJQlKuOqg1MPoFPrYlUWxJUuOiJdQl6VOhDv21Oo/pNW/aoQ8IsUxH1TKF6gzc1GKuOoTq1V/Oqm5tPHWNqgVWf46QH6rVq4BUwB2AeXuReP9L30huS/kad6sSqAucG2rL7dqsaqNKUmgYtWwNPFKNXCYN8j08imkY87VCWi2ks@lcWiqiKwz46XwaHEH@AbYjYSVExsR0ZpaR1bRqqOlE5pXZe5VMnySAnSGksWR64hzY0xEDF6gqbJtkhTegJ6VtWSCX9Rymb0vUWIFkVLFggPUhG5vpIYJ6ZugWxUgmJZbdSlibCQyzeTwdHzRalcrBbPx18EpIb3YKqWIm9TaZrCY2kjXPeCPUq0IdyQuVerwBLdefPmXedNSAWgaTWtQqjUYHi1jMpLOZLJTObF8MtsW62EpnNgoqVNElI7LBON2Izigix7NwG7eRL7cMqDq1rFUFmab3siVNKiv5rXyGTzHymMLYJ2@ISZZoisEB8kQ8XtTi8WS8issbG6I/mw00jehZHKhr/K66IwIzJlbEsoYBFqSRzghngtwBO3YpIK/IciD2nguX55fbdeErwnM8@bmtvcRf8eXjvSP8fQWcymAtvXz84ujF0QOBKbSlFBjP6kZVrrarYJHk@q4QqzAGlLTpa7dSNhj7sptVU9v1l/zdxOMMAFcgNeMN1qJNZIaJMh37BDUn7LA4lEF3Rw1Ny7YaWhHGPqCmQVBNU6uoLyqGxyXkukLn4nLFLJ2LE2Kzc8jsdorcv8bmcz0lBbMCd9nuILXJz/mUxW2MV/Dj8bW4TYx02j6NMdwS/7J6Wj3JlLcFQm7syt756l5tb/Bsr8rEbLEoVvf222AUEyxWFfM@0GruYfxZ/Dh@GN9O1sVSgVzLuziLvnraog7c1cmJ6p9FKmbaYjXG2mLeP/QXObCUE7fLTQG32sdj53EWi1/Cb5HFl2@D80wFgHGS2X4J9DAWZicZC5LQ2uJL5lVPJDWzDU1mlw51avxQJ4uFxzpxCdpfPcrmCixZDpZ2vhLfjcVxBaXiee8W5wV96GpbrMcYiCcn1dg2E0sBXt5mTqpiseDbymLOL2DSTwKkTmzRwXG7r73SoDPFbCdwAEkTZwFhsM/nccEiprwae59rpezjwyP7vvsgcvDrJWYAcoCn2KqVl@2NExU6UVbMnqRjbDdGZx/EMqSvcQdA@AlTqy8R8Ux8cf/osZhDZIHMBk4JKBTPNSTa3LjYcHCFioVbKd/ZH3@dsXE8m8OtiLXYrJbzt/Gr9bqkbmuoZK/IKjBk9tWClLmoc6JQJ4@CBj7vf@kHudl2CexaRgW7puVTWr2ubmksGRu//@L3UV3S@cEne49YHNc1/u5PfqQV/@5P/hVtDoxf0lqHli3GICQa1UIxdn4@Pj@/hIv75WOt2LU9ES2oTEUtl4tbcpVVFF3fKqZy2q5dVWJ@AYpqMuZJMX8DbLaQlxIJVYFcbWVLmST4XfghtUwJbMGKHw8uFqCioAAHz8y8pu5u70D5drI5rboB7U0NDxGz8LdteOWYECs9fnXBGFi69d5gYGpkUhRWeSex7XfSNnuH623vpA32qlbHnR0qHj0O1qO28CgmrsrG6yllK85AxGT1xmX1spWiBS0Q018axpbdvIKN5gaexll22rLhZ2x59MNIgYMH1sBmbL32xMRWUlF6PfF6/942WL4ODWZLWRyQZlvBMhX/SVIz@f6XfkPTCn/3J7920b5of6aBmF4uF1Qt9rOfbU/tqWf06j8DADeoyglEbeK2UacNGkIRnXFFr6YfKzTIXVGITW0UR3j4QGBHEZ0BK2cObKNHArtwiuwnVW6ba2vsJSjYFmrSSJM4Q9rRklVBCPh@Lq64g26aYLAt1E7caCWFc@Gr6AXcDQORpyp8dQEKHEbAzzjdtmdN3TGdZkpQPLWVZnchCqTwVdSEuUEaQPyhUVKrTNm6HpVn2SOsEavKRobnoV5NGNWFr0IUX4W7NWdjHZXVYEjThrFYxiCUT/LoNSDtFqRt8Qhtck1Q6XmANOO545FsEGmErwJ3RlgwgWlj5jYEqAL9@iogAMqQ8AGbLbbNskl2bqZS1YXSzks8VYFqRfVAUYaA0RBaDxWzBJGrGA6cQJTCjwZju/BrGHjmiGMAhMPgey5qIIxhdLIhH0yabD4YFMAirXEJKhq7e3eRq1rN7CUZlQjhn5hjnGakerBX5xWABYLsnV5FTDNUh1oNXMNmBxhPUXah1UlcD2o1EpWJaL0UBPh/cKPFFnmlqsijigXw64v3ii6gDCIj2nkddtl2jalaMcnCzHch713KFKkrCKXz5uyOrH0WeF5CDn8WCz7JBUTrODp167fbq5pSGMguU/weEurL48TA13DCNeIh8TucBLHDWFAU06LQfdMFuZE2gwTKOBNZNYnRFspLKR9Ex7Ucw@MH@SS@KBaGZvDWUamkn84GKcPqOlCh3tixSQslacnCsx/QIoBG@Qr8eLan9hl@P8@vG4oczZFHyvuw5WOOSaumg@qGKC7uxei4hn4S4CbNjIHMuqMe08osQQ2NFA3aIbgkRaIMd0D8QBx3LGMEWXpuGHSm0KsoygBY0mmHtC0@NqFdDR@YMALZnnKfI1g5M09M5RgVWUtOH48ect01MeRisfvxbR@@ZkPLcU6YZZ4YfEY@saT5x2MggIEMkQbMLm5AbAV3FGnZNM4DqWkeCu4ivIrcWEpH4m4k5snr76y6kWhjjV7QeGNCrVjGqW5H8EvXheDPPHhzL9AdRhqwwC6HJNfwtQbV4qgPJFSHJfha0GqkgEvGlZ5xQoyJgfYwNApj1zhlOIcg4BgDRLMb6OHBXgyl/SoNANT3oGehUtGJW0HtUZATt5foQtfzCbzN7rCsJmBArtrNV8MGMLDqa8vQwQ@iYjm8SQ8qRqblDaQr0DtHPfBDvSV@88P4QetGMyl8XTRvtuGDw0GH0qox3i0CSz5iwd6B7ZmKvgGeBcjhipxsJMQUgE2JSZGDDuNfjc5bu0C0pMKuQ0ozhOCjGqAQq6AjyUGtkZEP3QngcU/3@NdQfJWjZ2dnMunBnbqmbHj48TfPsXVLGQ9MYL0dZWKMxv5nts2uMg7gLkwS/@ajPB6Od2bI3dbKd@f8LQh9r@bvykrE@14cB8dT/LbZYEQ681BZnUcN6oFJ30XsJvxNYrz9aa30edD@Ktj@pFL8EoGA1AZgZul5upsGYOlO9yTdP@tVfY9T6pAAHGrRCBxRO7UbWEZeYDLH/TCEM0E6Gnp1rBNaLwdIIp8wXyTNSxiEnAdW3z42ZxDJNs7Ynuvq8wT5JzE0NuDEnNgeNodhn3zAiJriz7mqZHPWmLeWos/C6DCohbtFXFSIJ5zfDJTrzUb/Gfefgf@M@88WiQbJNmYtzpKh0yUWB1s96lENQiKYeRDmkuuYXvgQZODHQaQiNww5X3K7hLtbo9gBvrkN6rEWNAxoE2NAuJFQGi@bjWbL9oyzrVZKGUBjFwkRUOMAutEinJ71QjNi3zq1xo635GSj@lwYlfx8o1N36LcG3lawjGEFUcPg@DJR4@lg5G9r4QyBX2CAgHwYeCJrsDdJmMlqqKidPKHhNMQFjnnGGn5mWsR9@V6@G7BLHPUcsVFArQggdA@LBNkEHxb0HP6pz4A6fOo6ECYIK9HXCUeoeS/eigMmr3QVTmuqVEmRXElSkE1AO7KrtatFCfyhKhpXvCLFvPTrP5r9jS@d/T70i9W5pwbLB4yqEO0quAUVWAi/uxBWWb0WqVfIgbKlW4YLI9cB50/90RqS2VICMYOng0XwzsxJd5iIVH43yeuHzr6KtlgJm8K8VoMizmu8W/J@EaCUIzyM5vnR5kFD8ONzAgIwMiujGX60WTTarFbjhIPN1kQ7i2RyRpmc8Sg89GxNJlt@NJCeDoPhBaunBdwp7pEVAZ7Kh1Fgg8Yi8/RTAzcfvEatoLhI46e5oDnUCvw2hCw2trNua2XqjUimI0TrCgBsiNcA9PhXwyvCVYKnSqEtpFEclQGN4ja/GXBaAQ2MSHCVa85OhI2MZGBg@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmmjHX4bfYjpwDG71umNmOaS67JhJX/n9gzi2ELORDhrhPtRMDgkySjIvbF/lbJTniLG9KQg4wNV1zhyWWMFsg7sy9aMqHcvpKCMdNxHht4S5qzyeJwP5AZeq2O7YmegTJ5ercKHJpGa3Kn0uM5gD28FPkEW05wOv13MMz45PoFK7zsA2PSPNULHpieGLHYb/PQ8hyif7RscTBH87GxdjETRvV8jqttumbU7a7QTuEk1Wwr3ytGkUm2c8LqD8C6ZIfCBPPtCjccLpvDa6k@TtMPFTEH60Y7N7kjga@56o8GOPAQ3rAv8PvkPgYJjnLCRHUjOPrHRnkqBvmAydkTMArm/qyTjXLFwBf7iAjRnSx2PKS5rpKNJWIh8EoV6S6Kb1pB/1a186KvualtCTYXxtGcASMtLM/X@7@/69NnJlz7/xUyg2Gdyh3bZJIImJmRgwic8hkAskOVnCeBq7DT0xtsdtfniSzOfe@8e@wO7/@wj7Kvcd7l/7FGfrWyV1q21jyMzZPfvZfGZwd0sqlUqlUkkqVU3SGJQdzqiueWt1UszUd/j9@B7a@B7Ox5dX4ZM4y9K8KonfV/XjfAKBMiZoPL4bDTSd5FZ7Cp0UKvFn6FVS4N4ottlIrw1Ma5S1prN7HeIPN36L6C1G/P1t9J/fgaZ4/b7d59OwV4djkjcXsHfNc9TIyJw45yl7w4Hsma4uZu3te9ZFeRGwdwcqBKmxLLh68JBNA3NAy@4o3kA2gO/gedjFTfE9G8tVJXEGTsMrV31eub2LtpvtoOuPg3Ze53QtuKbFB7RgY3l1v4ZD0LHQ68taL09zlxOn0jQOokumyi0s47tXjnM7W0mWMOYe3ilnDBu30w/pU6IZW3xV2a2mdcDSUg7bsVchtj8H48FYgjB0JWSglqMy/0hPwn/H3QQhOsjsWXaTap154vMgHzfpHjNCnNdLNxk@0g1EeM6a7sPvI9HdLaXOtQpVTS9n0uGHZvd4OK/HLa4wPCmHUfdjybuY7t48Z7GaAEtE2Nb3TSFTkGEm02rlbYjyZW6P9XtTMgHfeJ@ud8us0pwhUOOSLOlGIS@3Wb9wMlgZN@gXG07v6RcAz4JRUxjKtA17WjoKr@KUC39gaS36CynpBMWiopBco2Hlyphnyv7lW1xn69Y6W1N1tlJ1xiMgXaWVKdNKVal7Ad0zrwu6QWd0i3RGEtbO9DNPbNO/Xt8fYrfiy1K4VAldtXS1VCGBvBQsVep5EspL7aXKNj9ES5VDfvi8VPkrPSRja@nrUsUMC2QY0is/vMR3LcLx3lqqbOWdb5mR/zmITL3eUiXuU8rzo7wyRYgUaDdpjThi6/V1M0fDgCY2VipdBY6JXCyfeB/G5f9L9J8EFONQQ0jEHucjzqyWVTk1aVgzhtRD04YJZTFjJFf0bF7f32EzszgLqlmmNZ5dhsGTGp5bSgsjQQypfKJBv4Qg5GZlNkbKmsnuiY6unTiUOzldP1PPY32gnef0Y8p8klTCUeR0edNfaRDSgffDE4Vvw3MKHVMdY4QzWWcGWiDqz0tzGoW@TuOie9/uId7rTmcibAsmi/QSg7VkOulwfDiHygb9QZpJOBVXHUK7DG/KyaAE904UY6mgR@YtyfxZtwyCwR78zrzmWOWAWkoEIfG4dCKjLJ4XWBYjKZF1lqYqg49QsGQOjfCg9Zkj9G3rR84n4sblueK2aciUlSpZcqXFJBX24I/s0h9J7fHitQ4vZd@3fDUlb7DXkgcAq2Rci8jX/nfo733R341CbYgwUcEsxXr2VDqtXs@dZScw7ybVTncgEl217cxUjuIaEpLT6sDSzOfx2pSKD5MPUfKl0hj6hLZvyBavCe6g2@TaQmBBSxhepT9@XqGPn1duJ9S0RtK98ozS4qEmDUcaHmOaNG0@rtLwWV2MFN7f9rvf3cHDdAfbnQd43IDhBMlllA8ve2zlkoxtEtvyBSK1XFEiyPm4NO7m5COJez66jY9t6cN@82B7f2/3I026T58@dfQcPU7ww6jFXms8jwtktlmP54MZy5YVF2G0cNiN7fjovD8cPfjUy07JEhHWpAz4VIthPz3GHS3LLHk@MXapnOS1KKphfU6GgZ@SSlB1fEzZoabriAgSjPKPfA3EqLdEb5dXaw4HjGo2e/5F0Gzy9GUiiOtZDF1jTsSdv@ceFC@jIUfKlmhn15kM@wFR2/vqw@vakTp6XVc777b@qj7uv1MfantHcADx9t3mbmNL0f/1vcO6yqQM8hAZEgtKout20AoQ71etlEpPFEPe6g/GInfyW458P/Qv1Ot@K8Ax1YvIv3h5Li9eLxhtSKk6LUfH2MMMORLoRTiCvQWHrqRlLJSbNl/PxCULRXlPaU17gTXvRb8ddkLKm8HadxAGkbnRp7oh9SDJW3Op3RUlCVEq2XSIo8/CAuuaivuUH2c3BMYX@yuQGDkkrGXbU5pw8b/vpuBR/eDNoYIvka39ve3GUWN/71Dt7B/Q69uPjb1XRM/G4dFBY/Mdkjjjm/3txk5jq8YfBIGSp@Dk45fLaDQXBQ/ZmSqtzzj59gbU/fFbetcbGry69vmiaqSWLnuQPqHfDX8L2kvrmcsI6gsux/JRgcov1g5evac5XwW/4oTTHAWz/UH2XcSRUxdL6gXXRoNlg8bbuh6uNO0Vyg6fR1yMFYInBevs/CPPz64ywNmIpx0GKrsFGxXsfYuPEB7LBjRV9IBgA5QxWKkqDnq2tOS@YJAbVFur24ePV6lNjAj1C4q@NKYm6xmmmLaVAVBcI2n0sB9UXo8/EN/ThxVd7WgoGdTj@INkUE/kA1TRBmxH1KrOcTnav4R4Vmvy4ZeLwQ4fC6un8YdNn1exzzRO0m/cpb6Kg0bCY0qXQ9vJLg@H3/WjVhhykYjzI@xbtysDI5CAoyQT5SiRbdsoZ5aETQdHDdrsTQJ5I5W4AXZCfmcUqXzV8dQRjIOCXihBBc@6fk9MoBLTHeY99Qzuqar6HnwYB@PjizmDPjMgAoGm8YjLbWutMLhvOSq5OVWjr20kOSCuMUG7C4HNKQT@CBgCVEitdFo8U/HdYYDpdzQr56M@cST2bX@38xM7ty9bQaqAttrK/xL@9pujieym1knGTpGxoy76LRiSWslHmZ3@kMY4i1UOXwYp2DrvD0ah9GE@3QI@ceJpjnJjYqPafq5upGoDHSZr7PV7VqWnxMW31HpKTHmfWpnj5ew8Fl9JXGvifJqExe4O6Pin/avAOjtzcYh0HWD7hRRhPivH5ud4xJiI/plJZMfvCuFwn1U3tjc/FX7/2UVMXBELEpLaGB3if2JM1EXDg8/52GBxCL1LjzQTyzC6PEVpbYOnpSVGuQFG68DzkNZ1L5vrcZqYG09/x6Wlye/88evXqpQqQDLpOObReT6Rbq46NlW6XOZEaRMQS3YSsiTr8@aLyzBjef0SF5XQC/C21IMcwbp9IlKgFiGmdaeXHZIsOmCz7u4YvqM22KIiiXaPC0h2fxR/ym9WlzecYmJQoixy5o2Idg3ksuNYZik8X02B254PjuT3/cE9m4udTA/fBW17LrTvwq2wfDssmZYsWPcH@/scsDK5/SGw1Hb3dsAySU5Dizk9Zk53MRdb086v8eepvuOxR2Aw92IHJQZq1XbZ4yNq4zE9LwUcG0yiEB0ebdcPDlRW1idUluQelgxtLQYB@4F6m1jbhj0Wdl6sNMWL5Vh5Ml9SFm3m37zBPJN4t4gKrYO4mh6xsEj8snfCG5F6emZhFYKt71kgGsqlsftiZFB0rAF/ozUgIZt0mtXAzMxm5mTyCSPbCFzTzRXd2LbhZwtrmbsRBnk4tgHZNkH@GW6WzO6/D6IfV0w9omDB0xQa3CZNmuYbWiccUsUDyuh56R6c0y2mS2FkLwp2ztAOhl@ltIb95xmKGUmUcNGFLbGulWONmujHi0bNYYNETAM@LD11olg0U4IR8fzlhd2hTjLp5dNTECmZCIz70uYKKn7yTU9hTI14nqzGCrk91hYZm2OD5Ql2ZzXs9dszPYQt9NqkeJisiqTt3KoK/5iqZJZI1WRoPrMxJpEgr62uPr4L9mQrTPHCn4Utc8ik/BxdDGh9n4CMxhFv7xPnNvZck54wwBzSiWm9GTATBUnVmTGnpNrOk5GNH@Ei@0KEDKIOINbwZK2OupnAbTZ0mZFs6Jxlqg3WEI4bKqNmivrf5lcHgXxnfQ@@vz4ZbMgE08FvsMp/0x9GQXIrz/KcY32Cx4H0t2A47HE2uc90ASh5vsY097Id37YTg1dpFRL5vM1uSUffThKzW9fsNXAlvL3oIbw4dvfWJ7f3CuV1u6k7jd26esQ@RjupvcjsMOtYsudB2JuHAMtg3pfA9MF3@B5GFfqfcHANSCIT3@bLM22cO3FjipDWfMxxqLRZqJat5cne70QtvwdfK272YaSy7g9UkHdh6/s7zqyd9dJ6qjwhFw16eSrlZgtelovSN2zoAlIahPQmvlsTFm5qGEtJXK8568M@CgdbwY3snrHlpF8sPyutPc9w63ruyL04fn7iPmpVs4omX793EV0Or9ufz/rnVx3VVYNfTm9a499@VWr1iXpMda38IK6ey2vVIvvWfUp/n6nnJeZcjeCPfFUe4a49iQOs1JJK1uHrD5TDD7xoruCGxASXqkcXhgtxxW5UvTheO6n2qqX1i@PeyTou@Y2Wq6Pl8nIeH36gWZRkjJzMH49OMKfau65B70rBnSrHm9VXQxRfDaEvb/xh2N@t7b1K7cZBAcAWmLb15g11CS2@AGs23D3xesF1Xm@TuQocm4GClFngW0FluATg/WRsx7RDwox6xSVtNrrhv2Mns1DyLgejPqcYH5hgLfU1/JpZMNeYSryjQFmOQ@MpE/cLCE6SJ4@DIfk6FivqQlnUtTLuTjoWiGOUZHGY/ZTN4k4hENV3uY5PMpEX@K1zINEltforF1MvXii8EatFHu/iwZTDH/KFidIJHnEAQj8DPm1AFay5R3ztI0PNx3sZD/KF96hGfE@GDeQzrCkiBebf6gvfb@LyL4gAQvgF0bk8vcWpNS9SJOXuIG8uwMFceuGPYwZcq5ROWUBjAVvqqybA2VKcaYRqNZno@8I1yCm0on@6BYUyv001I87vSHYmCZ9T67cItOQu5aQN/HSTYnmrWMEUM5ktUizcSQ3sdNHy6E1Aw2qstoJul5AWWiwk5MAj3@/V9S/H9UfHqPMkRl7SC1PphVS6J@mCVJLLowk@yVSxM2VzX5J831Q2yeZO1VVVrLx41NMtj1SSJO/6vLyRN@o3wyTzRtyVwpVxwotUQsFK@WlG70vKg1SZmMHj9GNJ1/y9ons@xjKV92W6fvxmdAcFbDyrbU0muNTrhd0fMzoMu04Bm2WJmkpJcQ6wqcygquo7mFqckAaHfX4ethvVBMpy2UgcHjPZjRcvs55WMn7MT6IhtxinBtaMMWJRietcZsLd8IVFqoeTH1ggGCYYTZmRu2EKj3XhsQUWuR6YauUW5NQAp6ZNDvEq7kV@xR8z2NPImXy52YkLgvmNNF5uN6cJxEL3QXY2mdLSBNdF5KNu1JxZJKl7PAlxtpDYs3aB4zoDuYPdwTb4g1hO2ILCSIopuscpmtJJhrJh39u6EInfMn8vPsq88knHHnSDG1XDMsPnW1iZ1AX3URCNInjbYkdA0eVg0MWpIyt813yFWkcvWFnFcUsC0ZrZvUwDlj2S38WTvpBOhTy1D8jXMBBJEqLLszNcJsMN2P41RCt2XMKRl6n1xrKhQWPm8YpcMw8UnG@wAO6GZzYS0nMyekDpaOC3Ai9DOlpE2k9GmtoJdVxa3k/HvRE4daMprZLJ/Mtl2Pq89QrnuU/Lpcdli2RX@ji45D1@klywIiKZhBX4ZVwtP8lkrLPhlpwNFwDQVbuY6N8TbwZXQa8XZGo0Y3DGiJTWKBheBW0vkzkI4kNgwAUr42QS97D7l8OWbO6Q0uUTM@KWcOTKcRhxGH4xP8txcYvPytwMDq2S02bq6quwDQKaGyedPk6H@cACbgKEHih0EYyIKI8clUaJz541Lqy7XGAjiqgBPyfW2URMhl5/FLaoZ3gnK9MlUHIMklTWa09gQvW1uj4uB3uzEMD1mIQCBgFzlDQPh4w@NP8uHJRumDlj903PFEn69Xms0HAPhiFJ34TA3CtczMKdOvjodeNQHe7vHH2oHdQVPb892H/f2K5vq82PfMaNg3L2fqxe7@@SdIlP0@XUfJ8@ZGuHVDLLCZna3kdV/9vbg/rhodo/UI03b3cbBI3AH9T2jhr1Q1c19rZ2323z6TtBUHv7R2q38aZxRNmO9l2u1RTLJOXU/o56Uz/Yek2vtc3GbuPoI9e40zjaQ2U41a@pt7WDo8bWu93agXr77uDt/mFdoWGZ7cbh1m6t8aa@7VH9VKeqv6/vHanD17Xd3YmG7n/Yqx8oNhKwWrlZJyxrm7SERU3czu3GQX3rCA1KnraIeITgrqsO39a3Gnio/61OzakdfHQ10MP6v7yjTJSotmtvaq@ocZn8HVShftl6d1CHByVQ4vDd5uFR4@jdUV292t/fZlof1g/eN7bqh@sqs7t/yAR7d1h3FUJictUEg6hF6fS8@e6wwXRr7B3RnPHuLewdHOrkD0QYwrJGRbeZwDCDQGuJSPsHHwEVdOAOcNWH13X6fgCaMrVqoAIsKraO7GxUIRHxyG6m2qu/2m28qu9t1ZG8DzAfGod1hzqscYgMDRhkfCTWoUrfcavRT4SXPBKzZgznutydqrGjatvvG8Bc5yYOOGxobmGybb3WNPfgAdnaRAn72DPwL@yNlc70p6sAPj@nd2Rm79HEHpO29rfrNCNrZ1fZJOEdzTrPJlwp2Wk008SJ9JpyWdMOTi/PmmGv08cd07iYbHxcRGcu4jo5CInzKTMn/JneX@ECuVyz@b7WpIXuYbPpuPcpmULjrhJ6G3xeLke3EZEvsPLGxk@lInR/kSLUxg/6oJMN9XAAgZxC/R/E9M2/CBxVLLYDXQyX9wHYbB1FcmxyjqMUEo182RGxfJIqeWeC30PNDlwwb8B7rSb2SWEZyZn6Ef3pfU1eZHKwPpB0lu2uYhGLWEYj/C0w1Ugl7BKB/2iPBGGHq/SiIPh8li/Z1WHN7531@@2845gynHdE68CzvHNH8dPgbKJ4YbI8I8vHzjpoRGTW3azCxOfPmmRK94s35Jbl8ac54h/HYCM@H7BrylXxZrXetMz/IMVhkeQq7doC1yu4k6Hzvan9rfEBq7nSypP1ie@v4@8ytmAvCO/ANOEdc7kT/nl9IhlogLEvDiJJqD1kFItWGWNvEme@poznyHQdtmH5Q3P1ecDzOpGEFNlLv2vXidl4GN7Y2JMcfnVQe7P5bmeHRCewffJs9enaeiZ2u/U3V34/oh524MtexwY0j5OexknWKNkixYdHiuU/PWF/ZuBiERnhNd90Gn@En4fYbiNtyQRBhuZGCGzVg4leNgAdsoodcDzIGH6dOTI1A@RTTXXQmgv/hlV8n3Ql5gFtzNIdc6/d4A9gx8PfDPG4QZqBNIuxS2PiXFpdsNzL7hhTUV7csOMeZPGyho/FjVtMA97qYvtZ3K7lN83bVi9GYsqI8crdziUJiQeTWChjV9GTkf2W/YzoDWD2HkZf/qb5jR4/agd37O7Oj0a10SGRcScuiX3qZDNaN/pYQz5BFBM4VTM1vVDY5Xc0Ujz29HZy7BjEGg2MCkLywMY3DXg99iMyWSVbwL5cctQX4VQ47wCcdc2x@p04d1ZzNJR14z9EvxuvFEpgxU5OhGrXcR0Zk@Vj7MfCkDNFpj9FD4b/T6TJDPgvaMVJ0BNqWU4A70VJhiq0ouUrEyW8NgcN1ulGQk3708cEzDe7Y87jhunTmxu5X0Mk0L0zNh8@stvDTn4GAcDk2Niwx29sknbu09LpZdbRxXFO0mtdDPJKzxVmqpiCW1g7cVntcs3ZCl4c5chek1XhLhVVL2XhdsqjnpZME0t59TDKCjjH@P8oPuINkHjAM5eei9XqJGeV9CgzckC7WrImnHbsMYnU0m@3nto9UpaLzJTs1ydfhlAEegP4TLeTw7n0lZjnpj0u8kysjtgLHty0Y5mMyUe7rDtlQ8xuADgP27wZgogvo2tMEF2Bzq76Emgq/5ANRVBJYnWY@BmEuHU8Ii1Pq9cx9rwzCQ6NsX/XkwgBgexqmRyeOPjQGNrX5T31xh8Tyt37NVtYrPjosO/CdhGVybaELo/oNq1@f0iqo492E45uOHY89UFvOgS96HKo/RfSfBYO9Y6EUfqpGqhNsnrnaUZc8zNqUTjCbYW2x/zBTboIYCEq7kluCmsqT8xreHTDbDqGN8tllX@RpLwgmrBbUibiC7Wmvn6VXEJQ7TI0YAqGUby4YJtNrgfnDvHwu@4PP2PuhwrUawft2DOpBZL3AqWTGj328dgaSdMH/Yh3NKgrsAMSU6IsG2mxoSrN0U81O2m7pmziHRO@S7kl319PzKTGWooqShhX107Mt1agzgSVVrRr0NhZaHlllVGZteD6dutijL2Fpo@tVfZTLxYpFVEiqg@N6ognkZvx00c86U3@6sMIo4e@4Ixbq6BAGDorzlWn5RzjB5uCD2EwbNt7oqTJtP0Btt946dPvMS@arUPt9q/lj6JgTCuAVjG8KTKMZv4v/fNec6vf9c/CfujTOg1@9W9E4uFxzI/osLNh/zriwE0SjdLK1B4nz@JfRtyw4T0@l1y3XHNFo2CQt80URsNx7VzcRPDOOYwAk2izzN@DSR9pcZknq0mhTPr@KdvjlZ31W8s@Ls8qLCf6AKAF3MaEBYXcIR3xxSTr8un6VIbTeRksHE9VQfnOLRZ7KYyfE4n4GCaFsUFmyizBbgRWZrdifNy@cdvsg3AIR0vBdoBAQ1GeP7s@QniTFPkRlgIVVX5WsorKKcoN/BDiYXw7uVee/pOxJwT@BPrlx7O4ZRYjsIjrGG9LkaxXtJdRwoXNA0OW0SyJSYqFZ2HPun7IUT1uJqGmk8e3UYMtf0gp0m72prgSIzJPCx/EF8w3SeQ0xw4mlSW15LDfDqggtVG@dDvDBnfZz/LgxyGu7JxBMG1pyHkL6dtI1SIqIUTyhHmtjbL4VL57xKys3LfXJghYnWVyZgXrzmeN5sI3UEKZX3Gs1R@SMM5OUE@beixFo/5g6Z7Uu1V2zPTMNovWLce50xBYmK1Kk@WjNpO2OsbjeD0zic8E06QpxpZmxENYvvJzzOaTRLypNjHeqs3xHXS4jWaJ3VQ8qcT93Zaxj0nxCha9ZqKJhxTjDiel6/H34yY1vHm7BNEwZXnVZInRhMhojuXRAjVBpphK96cQc5/GfYIebaIc6m0T7ez@uZWok0ZyxuWpSUo5uQQ94bgdlzZJLg06ML6AmzjRcGMhFSucN@6Yj/LKhVM4GUaCAIRWHBSSfSjZwU06a4KPODpAJ9@EtVAZkoieNmwLh9jpf0ww9sqvN3e0xUNzXCifrAukmxgSrSo41zxI5r45vR43bxjKFCloiM8gRdyiKdl0fv9W/dm2UD6CIKU5WVv6llw0xlHLhA39sZOaN9CBk6p0ydSISg@EJosGGgu0SjnrBrJchfYXDoXjYd2ghxEtIORzHj/LugTcea@VYmqjyE17jCyOJreMNkcVNqRIwlDyDvLroSiqLi9cCUAgGFP5apkgwK0pY49DAXa9Y3NeClHdR1SwWsawpI/sFTWx85yRDqLqDE9WrRylWTme2zAKM4GQYjE7T4II6SyzsyRQaKKbiYuV4@ns9iQ5SCE2vC8Up67QvZKmYdxzQkAO8V1yEolyXFZuSXMwJz5ZdVKJMX9z6vOSlVqaTCX6xBgeF8qTqc9KqdRUtSsr6aKpkkQPx641lUikcGyEY6nw5/7x1RTb5XlsE2otMlJahrbPRgh2WmXSus37JVIv@FK20TEMPPtmuFl@NSXESsop@3wH7GqJjwzgu/1Pt9ZYphpMdKwA9ktnLrvkZUHIGmsWUz2ahZWu8bQXOygwa9p@R70/2tlJuX09HRtDo4tguFoqlcDEp7bze2Nbja2ksF9M5y52Lrvd4uD6L8P3p0WW/UHAIQEqZgUdUJfQoIi8/vBMIkMAB8qK3AV9kRVr/ctOxw7BgBNKdB51m@TU3hAUT0BhbPTy/og3gBiknmB/RgPRvp9VPPqufVE0NRRzDEWlYRJ8lTWnZ0QefOjAPjs@qWJgEMzGmonmLae68QUzCCKbcGex@2LnS2KenH0ddLt9V31A6Gd4Clj4NllgZ8cuUJIsOGHk272XEfujdVVwFXate8XIYvM6wJmJycSZMH7h4Rv/IDir3wzy2eOfsjStUJOX0cxl@Kd2VfYs62hn8fcAK3xIaN8r94U/yLeYTpOZaarXIzh5Iowel92Za59UFof3xDTN7s4Nos5G12NnDdR0h3UB48ueu5dbckv2mLjZTzflDmhYEhgaJ/hcuV8JXDX754nFq1Gncz@pyGEApGO/SyJKJJQ/JxD5DIBHoB5@RE940f5rgYb1zoRDEVFwEKxjWu6gQBMFMpmHreqv1/laraYWB8vLqlbbpIdCQdU2a2obHzY31Ta9b@L9h@rK6uq6yNxt5wt93DQfv6lNgsE7nMut8@E2vVJaFffGYK2NLl4sVhfd9cVm9cXGelQ8rm3iWj89/ee//df//Pf/Vqzpl/@Bl01@Of4pzuR5XnGx9WXxh2/reD/ePllaPD1eHJwsna2Dy/7OXsP7jVHBT8xHveFpJiezgPWV7UjNOpu9z@iiygQPvPCHn0m6VFSuFRVz@mskkaNYxuZagfU9wD3KU1rCm6ADk0t5QiJHQMfYjqfeaQUwwKP5hihJuMAOVMrL2YrZuIc7mDhDfKqS0554WGe9CnCnJfGkgLu4NGMVwl4U9LADfsU6rzQvk/HpNxw1Nf8Wf3oTnW32b9SjT3n1qKQeuepRNss/5bXn9NVZLIa4nSvZaDmQzbqUkhwtwMxQRSErerx@4Fg7E@TOZBY5ZA8gGTcVnFluwbnx6o8vy0jAtegss4DYpkq2SPiQCUVyXxZ736hbvlCOb9nUVRtWFJp6FcOVWScqcf9CBfIjMQRIar4QglT6VCVO@vhGMp6K5ovu6wxHE2LAIOvBqx0e9/hAc9FiT9s8p9ZSCHPE5vPyFXPjulyGZrSRIvUnCPCBiiwnS3yTcCm3lBErb6uV3Ey5hW23TzOf2DqMg5GxTZdCvyuLCcSa2ybcYk/fa9GG3HK8orJhfLxiVZWdtP1WGavIxWV3FA70dQWuHQPqS1zbNxlJ6FEGJHDEZ39leoTxRoHxFDXRLRIsa6zafTRdRkJPX02nDnY8OTmyiFD8KU9j@@vE2HaKfEvEsIPwACMVm/J1/LAbaa8rQyb2mT88RXRAv8MB1UZybsb7eYhRO4FxvxMj7TFkNjlPxjM1JTcY@mcXvqtye/2joT9u0LRFms@o5TnUQrhgAhIYfLrqWc0zCEuLdJcwReKmsOUQghd0xzo8mvRtNr5zgi41Q0G7XcEgSLETUzL4muqrCTomXP0dnWCjPCW849NILWJZ8sLSSEPK2tdmeJhNDZ2MqcEeO/HAyWYE1XhkGl7QhS4x0V7wwS9J8i58BOi6s/oWoL6KsPYc9WN2Ogt6fmpyGnQz5qJ/cV3JvIjxzKEoxRopo6E8LScR74AV6ZE/pb1AyNxk3BllFvL5hU@RDueWs@cRdvId2@IXfRXGAeg4gBnfDFHveqEIy4kZKomB4akGW/4ThE7XPyP8xtf@GKz4KZf/8UHROf7pU@/kUf5T7@un3xzGRItkM8sWVE4fZhuJpccKzYxFN/VqrNIi42rwUy@d4VNPyR0WiwSESDF//FPx5GuREPqUc5xHxU85IUiqy4BJcX59RYAvTqGZS2NRzGUWnEeO6fz8j2VH0dzKv@hD@eDIL2FhFpW8TU/rnGGHQPE93V8v5cpJVHy2UnqyUn5CK6Gz4KYwDC4x3xaiy9PghlSJCMtZmno@/ZbihhQhvt1E/jp9vKF2SlgTuXsS6UtKWoTqYc71ZGK2ojKe8ATlJyqzu1RccXHiPD4OH7HgdxWxnMnLvqDEdNDivjzmz6h/gXr8CHJt8naIcCSsDMRGhLdQC4Bsgq/cxqGOGS5LfM/JU1vw3cpAqHuLOWu26PV7Ba2sOd7SOpRo3JrpPis9K02O0akhmhqhi1qZWnqgyhs/Pv2P/77/a26U21gpfhjS7yj3a27tWU4e6YHeHpu3q9xG7gWyrX3LjYu0BqbHp//xP6n8xl8IDlLGL@jPxqqBtTbObRSqXORrbmONHsorK1Tv//rXf6U2LMqKDbFYF5uuYsTWDUW2/B7zLqWrBlopy9KlRKzwxSzAEAtDWpvTCwyjblaelXibLqetKq4C7fnK2KPoKZ4Ns0ZsKiQ7GcaegjQjKVBFBQUBaUwoOsqy3TBmG2DeBE3180NvLaIVwM/anCOuMjbdeBjBZGhRlkXUgXmpkdbz8rBR@jEbm3dUssamZN2okFjaaVn77PE6scPbfjAKW2krCTNcL1r@dXDqgQ@9oH1Ja6pe1O3/MixeEUtelFeeFTvY3C@yHXdxwJAKg7H3GymCOhgQLQzZ6NRVQ@qB/gVceLkcLYgU@p34TMrEkyQtexC0ZA8rHZOYssgdP1eOh9EcL1Gl8/yXFHhEztSBIK1YaZ96VHL/oKKyy3FGycdrXgfYvGXjWO0CoyDWsAOWTV6G24DdQdMerzY840tIXApe1yWL57fbTV@n5TMLWRMqzc0snAfdQTXbEffu8J2KExNNf1Ezb4VSCLGDUCiwoAOsi2Dk0xK9muUvWI8nNcBNij5rjV3FJWTt6Lx6Vd@uctSVOVVfS9XX1KPQEpJ6Yp6xvLEpO5vIliq2KodBE0dqMyum2iITtHno8Q8wiKRbGh1cS9DN4RuQRLWkOdqqzO42l9fCxCPXgdzZk61FiVydySWXH12TQ25QQ3dCvZ5URgICXnArsFCm90O5AVE1YUbDXkb8@U0kG/8eGgy3YR@uRG23deJ8VKal3hVi34QjvkupiATar6xtg52R2SMGHbvYikPQZrHxknXAUp0KL7Y4o@mOCoeBNi6hslnZpzpuqTi8bEdHr5VAEfQhWyqvPH6yuvb02XNEOVvQrZ0NBoU8rAIG5z7BYI06T4tsfK9Ws0tZ@YQQ1NNVAvossDiAg1nXteMYt8/XzoNquaSBlbIM65rDaEhxvV3JIBOIw8DDjEBrlPwwm8//WDlGw04@tZ2v9D/xt/EPyAxn3NH6QnqrH94mnqkyF@JwoMqCmZ3i5B/Dg4qjU@y8Qb9zAG8TAWxdhe2pol14gBidD/uXZ@c2d3jatdURDRgiOPulxgrqVTBKHIxZWEEX1RsODev2RdXAO55uAYxyMSVA5xPgNMy030pfW5pidCzRJATPmrixiiNEy3TUZmfmzl5f1fe2JxHL2WHoGK5nW7aScseezOBABrF6reYeEXW1twu@SqplkpvyqswCroR8Zb4O7@OudAuBqC2qGFnNesMoP48sZebFxLVpUpT6EXjNgFku3U1Kc6/VtAIEMYJQ7ybFQsyNz3NskiU42Z2McQpezlYsG9E3YRSxgzldWdbRFqWciaMKLGRuAYh9m1JWGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIccr1WBmTg4zwVa3kTjARtRxQwu0v7G35artOv3Z@bDtQlHerP0V7Y5DPN@Ob1njW66oxo7pAttbLNvcwmbqV1xRImYpaYexCYIQvh2JihgkXgPqjR1NexnUx6mxfZJwBdjV10q42R3VgwSOXngPZEEv3mNXHHxdh79VZPNqWtLELlX0sJAtrvkD26LJQlJrDElIeQ8QK5MgYkctCbcvJAwvFuiseft67WIYu7Ezm6dTLCsLKlLbd4pE9jTP3kqZeWyxotlipYJ@nMcXzLdzeeM06PT1XbSYOe7gjQd/jDcK92eOwv8XzFH/53DHY80djyuQPcIdsdtwvtHJYdj7MzjmdMxzcLMdnoXYH@pYr2hEybUAsMADhrhDSonlEtp2izhR@dkJy5PzEYyEVlZxMeAPNf6JbvyTCmQuP24H/682vvAPbvyqbvxqBXPNjJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JEJcynP8zsXqi7ks35oy1d0y1dq2A2ndHN/9dbWvg/1NKnuqVPK/CYIAcO4r5@PjeLJlI73Go0EnMLL6OdduURx342VzpYe7WrWVo8dLqX0XkV2rr6w/g/0/g/gzTiJ4Shw1lEbBsar@VleSqX5UWz5F0OhUtW0hJpr/GMbrVXT1jJekRPUCKkeWNrqBcqpJC7kpicNnmJ/phI33jyuS/OItt1sEwcnFsLaFkRlp1kiIvmq4NkrqzF88o2@0BWW0cHu8v/Rchw4X/Wt9AIeXTtddDtmpnEXoIdxV6ndGOs5gD2oV5zpFhFk5ORHenb3jG7LNwu1dixxcS8OHuRIEdtOP@jtdQF9A0rKje2jIg2ni5vVlUwzTXLC/lCbZdMs5usW/yHuPS55tLnFXWgFwa3kcrXG36aF5N12srq6rw5QEp5@MEALLmUf86o@t8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/71cem)

fishr ends up executing *><> code. It means that fishr reads file in single-byte encoding, unlike official python interpreter
(answer #4).

fishr is separated from starfish with `-1 % 2`, which is `-1` in starfish, but `1` in fishr (note: stack is `[1]` before executing this code):

```
       /283nnn; 
01-2%+?/123nnn;
```

Answer (score 1):

## 383. ><> ([Mousetail's](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/)), 16565 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 |/183nnn;/283nnn; 
_|/1000 |/01-2%+?/123nnn; 
e|/$001 |;:n@04+7*aa\ 
#+------+ 01-2%1+  ?/383nnn;
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0-<?MLot ~<p>3:s4oya 8:nlet d=5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1997*.;  /8a7*._    /#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6yfX@uC/SmXogA5mcePLj2tDbo6r@vbSvrImrN@CHyj05@B5DImFDQ0ouf/wqekIeFWInNlEh7CadhoewFxdswz@BDh5icKbdP3OPeiNNe2rgoXn@SZxJbROSqdXUfJnt4NemKkzNUJr4Ab0yV88XJNZgm@f@efJKRb1kGzUmVkTmn@gPtW1zjdEAGHXdQqGYdKKyzQn4bAan0Rl9/IRdMJpEA6ldzWfAJitRvRxV/7w@5Gnz/Onh04Pnx3vHL543Mq1L/zx/UArbhtQCrSF3sj0RCu/jDZhzrj@e9EhYkBx9mAUn37ygXAw/9rRctNpS0RaFEncwzua5bSsKqTRQpEvInyTy1MgXhxhw4rCDElMF@dosKly7AClJgDrioEVKEyqtwjKrEh7rwGhu2r7/1W@jkS9@O6@CX8/DhH2V39BEB47T81P0DHb7FaT4YO/w0YtnByzI4KLVnJm9ybBWznON8FzNCtRT36Q9njUW96PEoa5qtfiDOCAmLsdZhZRQkDZ2aOgQLMAOqq/wY2@xxCbBBwzGw0pR/vM3lMu4jMcVkhA2HmQqDslCm6eGsrGxwY6hkbD7zw4/OXjGMP8H98kZUYQg2DGegP@zH/f490wCDVXBdwPdEXGFpOFHiGrBCFRDLLRXIM6p747Xfz2Qvh9COiLCD5eEX14SBPquDbTbM1IueUXxYJJ0gfGvHfp6IYOEqAkF30DAlTHU8eh67NT0TNRQgXnoo8rF5caOm@lIzajM9vDTiPgBRp0@rgNZn9oTrtbMV24Ug5YmhzQnzTYps/xTPGIkYHx7Axp7xwCBgXm2CeznpMJeQ0vE1acK12AiSfX4tSgB6AqZJGQyIwGv6Wj0lKarvP@1f6IMqgzMEzB/xzfPMvfA9iu@rQ/mX@Xmlwo2tOs6HRd5iWYI9bD6JeAZCfGPuI98EdLmWmMWiEPVkwFhZeYIqumUsI7BeQr8KQE9XsBJND6BSoPmBjXma4vh6RluK4GKYCuKgk0KhViZzuoYM75x9opC2EK@kFMVyKR0GgCkLzgMUCMAB5hMVqCbCKfmuPYKBKPt7W0m4kyWUStUec0qm/bLrPgqzOgmhBXOhpi5BoM4EGURA/zqfjQYfVJqEqMi9YqrcSRcPQeGJfLH4Qvtto8IkSUAWRxHBn4SYIYfD50Af@crNu7g5zYjX/fZ9AFJKoxJZEqKgq9n5YkzgeYDnXTx/S6uZwU3jvMhEDWGevyTuqRPGNujfL1nLdQDBJ8R8vuajDSAg8pmro6m0boVP0UQzxFERVzVfBsvWXPStFsKb5sMmukPVzRmG8y/rAzWtFle7r3r2mQTV3XBIrLY7nPbwSm7B1AYltAULauoheSiSLncyiL5JfKTgeKgyqoLSA7IFJCMrmG@dsbe3v7B4cdHT59f05hKIeNXgwHdr2@nmpKcbrRCQzxarOUqufdAef743oOgIhaZLkSoMRB@vyTqTSVZzMQjyMXJrqtFW5XDq6Vbn@NPue6Hq/nNajdljSJdy4ea@RLp0ukK6QGdkbyauFZaha18/qYsLeApEdD7/ID7tawmkueXjRbwy3Ysfr0lrOgIL2PyFnYCMDW9rU0FG/v1wmHBwo9dH@NnBL1oX8yu7oviZhYV8qF@jYlzslBZ6DtEPCLlDZIBEinIShB0be874kz6QrGmxj/GzTX5RfWURTJcyNyE8Qio4@C73khFFmqBfY24Q90bWmZHCPTDcc24gQLPUCku1@2WSAr@x2V4wgn/S9@zykymrZSJJFI7gpVmNynZDeAlBejQyN09nXpD9tQZ848N0JaZ@0ZgeuYA@b0/5VNsBvt4OoJwfXo9M2j5Eii3BJEBk/Ewq5yXAirh69idpVCLMaTXQE27fsHlUS@fmCXloTHrmQOg7YlkGijaHVVtsVAPLxaa9O7acZHqbFELN3bFj1BtQRTtX0oZ82yRAb2hy6bdM2aJ@Fk8WWlB@ugeP/v0NJ4UV7UlUgrta0nuXdUOHWa/qN5MSfSJ3zsD1curqEW5fJ1KgNtVwFxLYfCls3JZHnoCfbmyhpz784n7CIzARiT6I33MElOba3iUGVkTzYSdJtV3Up1rj7VZKkUCFbzIQ2YUs08mPn4ndHvOEkoNP24Krp7dw9dbc8waqiy3wEyJJNkmfoFwHzgu1HmaFEAIhigVAlvDJgRiBuSIdxKZN3CIg/4QFl6kJ3OFN32QjVZ5HMQJlZrV77LIFyWXOUexXK74FbpMFcsMWt91cigrAPYanQv4esCur/wJcAbiryzEFoT8OsWLUboxnpGHvtYoyE4sovE5UCbFANZCH3N36OKdOLChrwB/UKm8OH7QLiUVkYXapwau2cNVSP7RglDE8z8zBd1UWQoar3KJ7iOMhno@21y9FaqbfEAdRrxCUmNRNPi6kgNh2Vu0TVW9sdX7Ef1agJA5HAD8U7rtABzqZg2mJ1f4rSb2P/tZDJmNxKaqnrTd01Q8n6nCQ63mWZ7d2WxK0mYjU9vd1EGKmryZNUEmV7Zy90@NYb93OFCaosiyLKcoW@fn5/EHW0/Nl3lWkHqmVngzm19mC9k3s8usWnpzMlYLDfnNrCWWaumTFnv69LN37XdJcXY6fyM2E1ps/@hCVHMo8scqZXa@U8jGTsogfkK6jJ2wt3Cd9Bn@yfy2FzHraO70QYSNiyzWbALGVbEoKkoj3oI/ifuv4OKCf6Mu1@Wd1rt3yYauT2ZzZprm2Ov14HaGwEFqyecM5OW7QOl5BIU16U0SFF6jWf/6fEKesdmeMRhMD/S6hge45d12dW5OH0wef/5pcL3A6@2zSLS3/iePU6mEJDVWzFNU2no@hh9P/rOfbFymz5@2t//smyPF2MDXEb6@c/kYzc/V/J2NjTv37uVyaU3TuPnp509/cW9vL3c/nX/ayO/kpMzG9p/@ycaGpm1rykbL89RWvHFy8pmoZXKi/Gc/irefPv2659Wz/@c33tVVfBThccqKQCfgyjIVjPgswa0ij/WhV@xtDFq5GpvTrx0L3M83mFrfKf6X7x29iU1idU351IX3JPYmVijFuBEMYMsGttNYPbaNwQqXsblSq9XAWPwv/xbi1z8GOOgz34ZHPR/AKsxjdalGUS5i9QIYVE2DdP/vb3wjkkNOJmrExgXXLmvAJeaKmrjTgmuLrm0BtXpKGUUJwtmT4cRwmFq6q95FiwkWeNkGfh7BmDRj@Pl4drTL2LNGKpVqyW0JLvklTRIpqqo1VfUukAPpzlatJm0xrrc0m83fRd3rSZrSGjgwYhp3P/2HuGKrHKs/N7hnQqywsfvqfr0OZcrWs1v1FF1@R6I@VSyJjrMrsjR7FQcRpNF69YhxZct1MVPSxHQ6vdsm@wxxJc3CloQXf8ZioQt2WXbVbSkKBPFdY18@XOwArz//3/78@3/@Pfp9n@7/gGpP7Z7ZV7Yg0Cl0iTpcu5VKt14X66543kR7HdpRplKqlJT2ZTOxBRSo9YypmY8u4vls/Dn/tLvKWDNJseGiZOt@8mivxxbOde5Sj7r5HjwwOTC/FGRYwhqZQ6xdCwdDq79BXGqc1lsSMkQ1qaEW8i2Jx6oHV5k1dqGaRK1YFlt1La8dsd32jF9suOkxJwaSYSHAo5/f@qJs9dBnYatHnWL1IFp9EebLhgvzK8QaDaVl0IAQuLHdjcpGqVKoaEq7vv6Cphm1UlDDMJ56sdNYeHHMxhYIjYVN86pbUBWhhQUtmH2ZcFBZHzLZTbWULahi1TdpbSZWoZFoWUkbtMWMKoa9Def34dqAH/3hCq343CAX35mCXL82WEXd0rJK/k7hQMPx9ZYrmlcBxgnW7XQ6b7sd4Dp0vaN3dXWiT/WZPtcnnWln1pl0p12GXWZ5Rj/r5J2SM2Mz@stSLJtXN2N3qVG/a2ywZ5wKtVgquJqpW68Xstz2jWRw8JYkZxYTYv8AV13VVLYF41MGHsCUkRFkZvypqsBiwGidt95tNd5tQQetp7aJOLbqkp9LeMnt3VZKurxsgLla9f/b9dBYpYuboHCty1Rq@2UduI@X9UYKQL70QcoSI6Byu97aJp8wMT8133u7BfyLlNpubNecfbpl6iBSCyBuL@Vydzclg2kXYtY3QYBNbUrSBg6JDX@IgKCteiooDCadACbh/PxD7njOiRec3RVeIOZBH77cvqxfNrYvL7e34b9Nz0v/Da6X29f@9Fpca8Is/FtIWJoNpd5Umj6paIFdVuroIitNMNThDeEaWa3UaqABLrn13@ZfTi@eoQtmuSVDroXYFtuKoQrObGxLiL16/8X/gnfz/Re/j9wig59REWLn2KmVLZQ1y1zkhAezH9vsMb9sMOMdWNEFHR7X0dHmDxuXoxTllcwqfMY/oZYKSRmH37bTb6NWD5m9gqDXKB8TtVJBbKfUucZi22KhSMTuF65d8Xj8H73SysU4n6ZBtRSvPM97HMnlIp8QuKplVEm9qPMvL/CP5PzCqusf/cK6S4hdlJlRAfwkGEeMEIN2FFMUSYLhqr49wnMLuFAioUx6WvtMerEn4SSKPqFlsC6fIKgdHtTK5Tpf49l8Sp1n6/4WPFX4H2xAMVizD2Gb/Vp3BOxvs5/Na01U0x@TOm/w9@gt/thxF3/P3uCPHb/F37MJ/tjjDv6O3@Bvr4O/4xH@7r3B3@O3@HsxwF/zK9msWhU3zwkzKbWsXm7ORMJQNbZTb35l4s4rlmE3zF7L/wJVNldmyVjzK8asa4wnFe7Yj//0u9/8ZrxWi0tx@q5PTnVcpiZjDAPix0kZS1ahJtSMCiX04tXd@FcaJKLny60GBmmBrxCrsU11U81YmW5G7agdMJgs47LMMDNUeyqJMhmDZeaZOcuMHLUHJgN@GTCZmT7LDFjGztgQDHzBNGlnJmjqw2sAvz4AcuFn4k7djprpMkjIQqaOvhqqtjFm5qLdFBoszsRXBsiisipn5ILZwm8tNcRXr5rKVksrl5iMzU5uN1414y2xKaL@fa2cY525sdF8JcLQnRF580QXFvM8EHCrMaXZVDgmAUmE6MvLdvvgyf12W8FhqvnYOVr8j45GUeuN/9GR8/jIGTnwPzo6gs5l1FO7KaDju7s1oOv@aydWr@40KzQsBENDTNneadazEpoLKSD6GrqlvuS1gAjv@kZTiJ@BgHEGskk1ARLKWfW0Wj0jw6fcCoY2mtEx/J/5Bv9NEKqhfHMG1ymBJRsazz5thiZuUD49A6dPGchl4R8EwKj1v8Lf/G/r//gFS7JEo5VMnF9uJ@hK4i@ZPL88v/Sf9WQi4VsS2/BDB7BjlPPLOhop0DmYGolkK3l5yd3gmUhuc4B1SGa7TnEX4WDgiIVJUrL8kfiv@4ak/asZrwJfzGXvfIb6UUysMn2x76bZnGUyyWon@LQIriLrF7S5IVml70pudhpq609/RJ@P2UlSoHyuWlW3GLdoOa1azQW2YqlaLQWWzUSifP2qZ3bUAsgnuVwyWa2CZScAmwErxG2wdylWY014tu7e5YmUtIuLAGY2V0hlcL9TtRqklIdkDU/v@jT5/PCIvrwCpCYfw08ecVKSyNB3m/DbgHGxIt69m@gZuB28t7OXvHtXK2cuLkKX8Ric1CWndrtnuu02umcvLsS2SPtkynmwZ0oXF2qmnFLjScdNPMGPSkJSCUlld7Q6pVoGSq/liuDtZyC/vV3I1euFHLgUSvEkrrlzEg/5jYvxqhg7pzKopSKngGIVnaP7h6Av4zjBzi9jVKEsl08mgJAmgUu8jOHPRZrLR6R8PgmYuRR5SLVc5kGTLFdIlFJl/1fbAKkd2CD@Q14um8ptFbd2gSfGnzdbdSFNrp4bNfWydm5UcNb9str1P8@N2kuMu3ezZUBRKVNtCu32/b3jvXa7BmMZslLwQEei7gIqdXHjleou1atayjOoQO4oxWFIYCXAsqJt5dUSYkUw@6iNCHAgcPFpg20IGr3xIZQ5qjbAEeQbSK0HF@uxDhvgxQYozTGTWXQxi3F/ena7YSCHX75vaKW4JPAFLkZ4CX63y/I2CaP200d7@wfHaW1bYjHtwd5@Wnv@4l5MRWt@YSfvLNqfHezdP3oBEZ4@Oth7fvDR4ScHL56Cu8fOFldA5f3n4h01rbCfsU@F1@5b3TB0Y2oY7bPp9OwNe22abRNqz5pCoZyByzyjDWUZ64tyVeHump7@@rXujuli73/47fc//O/e/8533//Ot9//zvd/@sX3vw33j@H@Ln9/99@U8/j86Rf/7Hff//bvgON/gPuP4P7JT7/4jW/wm@x/DPd/irj9sX9HwvFbAFi/8tMvvvejn37xqz@A@1/69w@u37/2k9X397@1/sZ43/vdm8N899/C/XscVhD2u7/N3fB9Lfxv83C/@oP3/@Lf8f@f@j80/s77f/HH@PAt//QHf/qf3n/z32ta6U//9ftvfe/9t775/lvfef@tf6y9/41/rWaij999//0/@Ks//L2/@sP/kf4/pufvfcj//Q/@6V/8r3/xv//FH/r3T@D@d2D6yV/8e@gqf/sHP8T/9/7gb//oh/j/n//V3/7Br//tr/xPZPhNbvh//uW/4c@//rX/@De/9Z2/@sk3/ubXf/I3v/kHf/V//Or/9Rv/8a//@9//63/yTXT8zZ/81R/9yl9@89t/@a1//pff/GLN89s3Pr/4APcv/gFcPjyfHwLnQ8r1ZV2@@Lny8/fBxiIVaCfQun/5/W/8EjTwf8HY@2//GA/6wb3m/2NNpTA/5rb/Dxi062VGnwyY4P7199/@LqLofwAUwT/E13dCy5IPt3xnYQG0/taKSL/80y/@@Y/IFjMqdVrGwcG6pJVSWyDQbJXL/oDtr/BAlF9ahhYC8FP6DlKoJb/vIG17/8NvvP/RP37/w998/8NfwdFaypXTe2lJvWV5DALmPyAcBix8SDgM@Bmmn6KpNyn1GdjYZ77nZ599JrQvFDxRunsBrp@RE78Y98ITp75X4IfueASVgXvj1asWrqku3BS1lLVtu6po/M18rwzDhCTtTmpHUTXfy7hQNilWtWLvZnKp4pauNyO5ZRRDTTG2o2Q5PPDErKeIcdkKGKl8ls1SfqlmjC8SoTsEmm2RcYZPckXvmYCPxX9hnAksRTPHfP0itTCSwY/nJ8GNQh6SSc3CpSni7Bhnrba4C606U7q5MsMSzGapGYjMYIAUUuB1D5j3Wi2FEWs8P2DlWauXGGUllapBuTE2j5NulxDE7B5BgZi11DPW3qrNeMQUwqsH6EgJ6PRMVDUxVardhwRrs/sMYSFwAvvqVa1eqs3qCO4dx0dqlrpHeUJgtdSs/g7sNYIJ8YTY/XeQlVItlaqXMEEsJK@edJtXUp4KR2VPsZRfB1if8NrZZeyOqJZEvuSwgQjjofGZWoTGgBAc/JupLb849A@MdG8RwjcoKT8Vxv13iLHd4bwuBgC4kiTLMoMbV/N32C54zzioFCULrxSHkKIWQS0gdGA4m5QSUlS/KbJA@rHa1pe@EBgWZnNzU4jVxax4JBPqFIW5JxU6SYGbC1EYqTCxUBbR2aBjJUFeIH6V0t@M4zJdnHHA7E6K37u7W@wOFJPeCzeBSamsk3NiHMp2KiVqAL/upISXIMQI0E4J0IUgz2q0LJgS0mnG5FoM/djR0ZGfCXJ4WRNS0My1rIp2XJyaTqcxiCHLaTmd9t8yvclB9g0y@fpveRORS99oZ5qWq4KsBXQCnFhUMFJBYEbHd@/eQa3Qbq3KIYiqzN@4peVK5AkOXCuPZc2D80darixwOZ6phRxjCZqyhSvJ8KBNAhpSUuC7/Hk2gisR10qlOIUE/MuJrWAnX0GlBoEztrE6ZjW4uAhZyicDz/0jtn/0@PHBk@NxqwXkj746b7THrtM1PC@BfntP7vMTHlq5kIw1Ggj6uKIhiREOKhmi5Yf3nx0@rzBebL8SEpSxKq3T@gUtq0JsPP50O@bvZBLxw4mO@ByflUXZElo5C1FjdSHWNVAwwQV4FJirrCo89gb3nBlLZNKimFYLKBgmcbkR8vGLzpShWl@uAwh6FZ77kLe3CQNC/VyixRA0Qn0VhHrd3wPIVKH@/OAYIhwfMVXLyEL9MzaTMUHpUqhbNcuwB5PhJm6mE5sZMVKmzUYmjT8tm4Wnmiuk1XyxtbFhnUuYZpOq7Rx3RV6C9VzCYnwVLiZ8VWBfBSe4IA3c6sj8faaHR1V/sx8q0EvwHX@imoeOlhRwapyDE8bRC0ahK0tLQmzj888nrF4HeVw6fCDEgF4MWbDfTTJ78lCmau5NXYN8B4z1zE9M/CKm3DO9saXPofMANmKXl5d9gHT4gGl1jaw8Rg@fl11y6YD5cqYLMbtSqb1Tc0VBO6lU3mU1TQAHYUvBDXUb0ABoX8KWwn9VDxLJZksK0CpVFOGVzWYFnGsWhIohMNp78i5Tq0m8DWZzKm09EfAjK/qspoWXH3Z2ZxE2m@Fh0Qc82GDiskzgV@R@vq0gkA2Qhrvt6JPeVb97Zu7ezeKkRzaXCWc3qMTsEupmM5vLIsbxNFMrliv6yy6iKLZigmVMWK8G5lgTHnwCT1NjIkMbko1sKSPEGrGG8P/3y19Z2h7Xsxl1WxmDUQdjblvRwdgBY35b6YDRBGN5WzHBOK1n1cy2Mq0LTNjmuncZqvapiRNjhqq@uZtY9wyrL@Mhp5pICWjitq/Lvh5ErPdqPac7xf0l1Z5s2rbh4kF8HiGXE6uOjVoha6gfhlQXsETyXBjUzkhdgGDUBjIqGnJt3RJ6csfpzWVvMrfwuJDluLU4sJvxwGMB3QAWBifZdrLZXKXBWvLYGe8IWr6YaqgZGHvwVktpLb1h7BSLlZ7ctQzd3clX8qV0D08i@cttO/lMZSB/9vjRw8lk/Myg40k7uTJEQNV8qERrp1TJ51uNhiimGpRMCz9DzumatLEBxMDQexK8cTHOk7RSCyL3TLdWi8d3sqomqZVspnQpLBCHOMcS1gWMmsKSpRHv5z7pqNiODVSqktbT5jlhodLv9y@3zlMLi6CfS9wG@LmU9HTnPLRWpUi4CpumJXPhCS56H9B97q8zVkQtXxKrjerCXiyI1dalsDsyeqaOp5KamfPrsQpAzTnUGCQEnP5lxXWcSaVj9B3XWATMqoUgIM/Q9QA58TJMrpnBFM@vJ1eIBJqdX4eSy4uXYawgW8LlJeCdIxvQ7itWrtPu3YZazrUOgHZB89kOdC5jsNjLl0Js69kn2Xodqvo8V9Ry@VxeyxYK@aIGA1U5V8iXoLNlCpm8pgGUXLlULl5Cu1aUdzH6pCLbPw/ae4U@KpHQK1wraqPFku@emNZ5KSvxfCSS1cvL2DshdufZJxqMrGuvBIzWn2hSvZbNl8GURZOWhQwzQdMkLStlVUnN4v8Wg4b/Dw@vwV/DJ8TKasIxqkp6AuMt8Ag2e4QqVyYOO3bwo1sDds/orgmxP9Rpa/W@63je3yPMPd0@4V73Ta6fOPR6qOOXB72RORmuCfFiPEItS4b7DwbhYNSBDCI55AHuwcO1HGdVgCJ78XRNKR@HXwQAZPBPAkDwZ4cfPTyOvI8P9vYfCgV27@jJ/SuvvB8ozx4dPDgOrUXuG0TNhyB@8eDRo6tW/5U7evGsP3VcvIUHRy9yi0fohCd3hRxcy4FCZwLiP9BKHCmwIiDD5YuBQRXwvMddkKvv@sZ8YWHMoPFTfizZ9MLzB/yEekU4Ds4q6wwpbcdgXa5MCwV9UnTpCwFqsSwIY2Y7Z6yYYT3HsnSXOf3@BjgOdTx3aSAnbFnYEjHpM8e1emdmz9gQHuMRz7KKn6zHTAgPAcho2iU9DcAFodpkGNVshutfHWtqsOmYrXWEFzqh0TUHQxiDz5wggNDRdQb3l70gvhG9Jjc7THga5HbNx7oeXIgJu7FSXhT3RfGhPtHrVdcovqx6mUpFjcefumJZHMOwrHsD42AGLZe9gJ6ku/O0OJHFB0xuxwa4qmI5YxRgvHEDOP6y1mjt5LSLeimTz/71b/347/7k1wc1FaeLmpn9jLS98/iRM2HvkJ@oeDlnrrNSxeYMYr4CxA8YZEY8sM8nyyQxaeVSvlTOaqV0qVzK5dVCPp9WtTSIm8UyyBsZtaQWSvmymi7lysCn5Mrgmy8XfS5bCdhqZasCYO0ufmR9m4QueQjSFV8RZW8TepLF9NA@ZaIBcUQBJdwJnXLfMmswxDI1w7JFBhB11mWxBw/2Mw8eiOI9tOCOkv2MKPbQki9lMsV7omiQz34JeS7R4XFKqK5SnHBLJnMP6mDKAeCXHkRxiJaDAk70iaKJlv29Bw8wnT5aNIwPwU64D7dYgaUIwWy0APNPAN6E0CDYHk8nRxk9QAsmiT4PuM8@@IniR0F20OcZD8YBPAxKurcniofcsreHPvtU7DzP6NfQskeXKLpggc4higMwDFzolqLYASN2EVHsgqk718ENP2iPHwOwJ7oozjl6EEGiOKPQevdEFNuBOybziZ@bPGK3QhaVl3qXLGX8iaIWZBqDZUNLVhRzoSUHZXv48BN9OOkZA37NXf7uQkkfPszq5mx68KDz0UedwaDjzvcOPnqGXvv7D4FfmU/dzqDjR@y04XIg1v5DTT8Zza9eUOrDdruiWyu9vtZu53T7ild73jYwhxDrDeTMvwaY0Ki9D177D9u7@qoVbQLYRuowgncHr3sjeN/TO9wruMiL3rNOR6xi81eUZkJAiQKXprE7ngC1tdMjves6VbTPaiyTRqZm3ihkWlXyYCOQDDLVS/TvJ/Cp48RS8nzemNUyrdqsVtT4lqh@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pVUNGG04@zuKTusIR6d@stSzxJ7mggJYjNnR1JbKitHU0tVQrFl1tTUUxW8LmTLVbeJjLxDGP4SDaKrZ1iPhKjWEzpilYpFoFXA5xMYMjv4GxPO5E4M/STZBJzS3MPUAQqK5tTOc1qPzFLz2o8X2yerM5qapUrwWaZa8B6@MWFaXfiuBzkAMDNdjIV3AaRENVySYQMKEoimQyJngKmxX7VT79@fHJ8/BkxhXV/WuSpayD1qvrWjx7uy4dHgQ2/lSA/QF7VceV9pFpLPpxpDZyOQUqRH8IwCxJf4IYHGl3Hkg9onx8wvIFHoK5J9vUWy8cPl@A8HzpnPGXUB1El5Zd212D4KQmzx/RaHUx6jyUoV0xPntEA367Xa@3aiFQmQBGDWF9j9J2FBZhDj@c91FJB0c/xkJ/v0a5lLqud2iw2AzjtGpPUVyOn90pLdas9/ILEvdo9jFxtw7tTNWqG6zquCPK2WO3v2LWp7el946nhov6Vw6NNYDfw5F@iz4zkJmseYOh9lGUupbrL7EXOnkxHCV2qd5LLTjjlFzogchJfDwp9TodR2zVRvKz2ayzxEoK@Abu7yRI9@V5yJ1cFPN1j7SQ4ZV71X/WZxgq5KskiCYQFXYnwg@XWWbJW/xq8OOyTSgVy41f0CUDFxACw2SMPCD02L6vdmsUSEpuxJCEpVx3UGhj9Ah/bkii2JKlx0RLqkvSpUIf@Wp3H9Jo37dDHh1imo2qZQnUGbmoxVx1C9eovZ1W3Np66RtUCqz9TyM/d6lVAKuAOwLy9SLz/pW8kt6V8jbtVCdQFMgBtuV2bVW1UZwoNo5atgUeqkcukQcqHRzENY75WSKuFdDadS0tFdIUBP51PgyNIQcB8JKyEyJiYzswysppWDTWdyLwye6@S6ZMEMDWENJZMT5wDezpi4AJVhW2TrPAG9KS0LQuks57D9G2JGiuQjCoWDLA@ZGMzPURQzwzdohjJpMSyWwlrM4FhNo@n44NGq1I5mI2/Dl4J6c1OIVXMpN4mk9XERrLmGW@EelWoI3mhUo83oOX6k6jMm44aUMtgUotapdHoYBGLmXQ2k4XSme2LwbZYF1vpzEZBhSq6ZEQ2GKcb0XlF5HgWbuM2cueWAVWnlrWqINMkX7akSWUlv5XP8IlGHlMY@@QNMckSTTE4Y56Ix4taPJ6MV3GRY0P057SBphE9iwN1jd9Vd0RgxsSKWNYwwII00jHiTJA7YMcuBeQYWQ6E33Ph8vxyuy58RXiOh0O3tZf4K758vHeEv6@AUxmspZePXxy9OHogMIV2nQL7Wd2oytV2FSySXN8VYhXGgJI2fQVYygZjX3Y/a2q7/pK/m3jiAeAKpKK8wVq0z8wwUbJjn6ByhR0WhzLo7qihadlWQyvC2AfUNAiqaWoVVUrF8ESFXFfo6FyumKWjc0Jsdg6Z3U6R@9fYfK6npGBu4C7bHaQ2@VGgsriN8Qp@PL4it4mRTtunMYa75l9WT6snmfK2QMiNXdleX92r7Q2e7VWZmC0WxerefhuMYoLFqmLeB1rNPYw/ix/HD@PbybpYKpBreRfn0ldPXtSBuzo5Uf3jSsVMW6zGWFvM@@cCI2eacuJ2uSngbvx47DzOYvFL@C2y@PJtcOSpADBOMtsvgR7GwuwkY0ESWlt8ybzqiaRmtqHJ7NK5T42f@2Sx8OQnLnn7a0jZXIEly8ECz1fiu7E4rqNUPO/d4kihD11ti/UYrmmfVGPbTCwFeHmbOamKxYJvK4s5v4BJPwmQPbFFByfyvvZKg84Us53AAeRNnAuEwT6fx2WLmPJq7H2ulbKPD4/s@@6DyNmwl5gByAEedKtWXrY3TlToRFkxe5KOsd0YHY8Qy5C@xh0A4SdMrb5ExDPxxf2jx2IOkQWSGzgloFA815Boc@Niw8F1Khbutnxnf/x1xsbxbA53K9Zis1rO3@mv1uuSuq2hHr4iq8CQ2VcLUuaizolCnTwKGvi8/6Uf5GbbJbBrGRXsmpZPafW6uqWxZGz8/ovfR41K5wef7D1icVzd@Ls/@ZFW/Ls/@Ve0fzB@SSseWrYYg5BoVAvF2Pn5@Pz8Ei7ul4@1Yte2TbSgMhW1XC5uyVAapaSDgTqFEvMLUFSTMU@K@Xtks4W8lEioCuRqK1vKJMHvwg@pZUpgC9b9eHCxABUFBTh4ZuY1dXd7B8q3k81p1Q1ob2p4zpiFv23DK8eEWOnxqwvGwNKt9wYDUyOTorDKO4ltv5O22TtcdXsnbbBXtTpu/lDxdHKwKrWFpzVxbTZeTylbcQYiJqs3LquXrRQta4Gw/tIwtuzmFWw0N/DAzrLTlg0/Y8ujH0YKHDywBjZj67UnJraSitLridf797bB8nVoMFvK4gw12woWq/hPkprJ97/0G5pW@Ls/@bWL9kX7Mw3E9HK5oGqxn/1se2pPPaNX/xkAuEGbTiBqE7eNam/QEIrojCuJNf1YoUHuikJsaqM4wsMHAjuK6AxYOXNgGz0S2IVTZD@pcttcoWMvQcG2UNlGmsQZUqCWrApCwPdzccUddNMEg22hZuNGKymcC19FL@BuGIg8VeGrC1DgMAJ@xum2PWvqjunAU4Liqa00uwtRIIWvorLMDVIS4g@Nklplytb1qDzLHmGNWFU2MjwPVW/CqC58FaL46t@tORvrqM8GQ5o2jMUyBqF8kkevAWm3IG2LR2iTa4JKzwOkGc8dj2SDSCN8FbgzwoIJTBsztyFAFejXVwEBUIaED9hssW2WTbJzM5WqLvR6XuLBC1RJqge6NASMhtB6qLsliFzFcOAEohR@cBjbhV/DwDNHHAMgHAbfeVEDYQyjkw35YFJ288GgABYplktQ0djdu4tc1WpmL8moRAj/xBzjZCPVg706rwAsEGTv9CpimqHG1GrgGjY7wHiKsgutTuKqUquRqExE66UgwP@DGy22yCtVRR5VLIBfX7xXdAFlEBnRzuuwy7ZrTNWKSRZmvgt571KmSKNBKJ03Z3dk7bPA8xJy@LNY8DkvIFrH0Qlcv91eVabCQHaZ4reUUKUeJwa@EhSuNA@J3@EkiB3GgqKYFoXumy7IjbQlJNDXmciqSYy20G9K@SA6ruUYnlDIJ/FFsTA0g7eOeif9dDZIX1bXgQr1xo5NiipJkRYeD4EWATTK1/HHsz21z/Dbe37dUORojjzS74ctH3NMijcd1EhEcXFHRsc19JMAN2lmDGTWHfWYVmYJamiki9AOwSUpEmW4A@IH4rhjGSPI0nPDoGOHXkVRBsCSTjukkPGxCe1q@MCEEcj2lPscwcqZeWIqx6gEW3L6eDqRq7eJIReL3Y9v/vCVH1qOc8Is88Tg8/KJJeVAHgMBDGSINGB2cQNiK7ivSMumcR5ITfNQcBfhVeTGUjoSdyMxT15/Z9WNRBtr9ILGGxNqxTJOdTuCX7ouBH/mwZt7gXoxUpIFdjkkuYavWKgWR5UhocYswVeUViMdXTKu94wTYkwMFIyhURi7xinDOQQBxxggmt1AVQ/2YijtV2kAoL4HPQv1jk7cCiqYgpy4vUQXup5P4G12h2U1AQNy7W@@pjaAgVVfW4YOfhAVy@FNelAxMi1yIF2B3jnqgR@qNvGbH8YPWjeaSSfsonmzDR8cDjqUVo3xbhFY8hEL9g5sz1T0DfAsQA5X5GQjIaYAbEpMihx0GP9qdN7aBaIlFXYdUpohBB/VAIVYBR1JDiqWjHwkTwCPe7rHv6TiayU9OzuTSVXu1DVlw8MPx3mOrVvKeGAC6@0oE2M09j/RbXaVcQB3YZL49yLl8XC8M0Putla@O@dvQeh7NX9vViLe9@I4OJ7id9EGI1Krh/rsPGpQD0z6pmI34W8V4@1Pa6XPg/ZXwfYnleKXCASkNgAzS8/T3TQAS3e6J@n@Wa/qe5xShwTgUItG4IgKrN3AMvICkznuhyGcCdLR0KtjndCqOUAS@YT5ImlewiDkPLD69rE5g0i2ccb2XFefJ8g/iaGxASfmxPawOQz75ANG1DJ/zrUpm7PGvLUUfRZGh0Et3DPios484fxmoFy1NvrPuP8M/Gfcf7ZINEi2MWtxlgydLrE42OpR1WoQEsHMgzCXXA31wocgAz8OIhW5Ycj5ktsl3N0axQ7wzW1Qj7WgYUCbGAPCjYTSeNlsNFu2Z5xttVLKABq7SIiAGgfQjRbh9KwXmhH71qk1drwlJxs17MKo5OcbnbpDvzXwtoJlDCuIGgbHl4lKUQcjf3MLZwj8AgME5MPAE1mDvUnCTFZDXe7kCQ2nIS5wzDPW8DPTIu7L9/LdgF3iqOeIjQJqRQChe1gkyCb4sKDn8M@EBtThU9eBMEFYib5sOELlfPFWHDB5patwWlOlSorkSpKCbALakV2tXS1K4A9V0bjiFSnmpV//0exvfOns96FfrM49NVg@YFSFaFfBjajAQvjdhbDK6rVIvUIOlC3dMlwYuQ44f@qP1pDMlhKIGTwdLIJ3Zk66w0Sk8rtJXj90PFa0xUrYFOa1GhRxXuPdkveLAKUc4WE0z482DxqCH58TEICRWRnN8KPNotFmtRonHGy2JtpZJJMzyuSMR@GhZ2sy2fKjgfR0GAwvWD0t4E5xp6wI8FQ@jAIbNBaZp58auAXhNSoOxUUaP80FzaFW4LchZLGxnXVbK1NvRDIdIVpXAGBDvAagx784XhGuEjxVCm0hjeKoDGgUt/nNgNMKaGBEgqtcuXYibGQkAwPDL6ZoHIC@K6YagqjSRDv@MvwW04FjcKvXHTPLIdVlx0z6yu8fxLGFmI100Aj3oWZySJBRknlh@1ppozxHjO1NQcABrq5z5rDECmYb3JWpH1XpWE5HGem4lQi/Q8xd5fE8GcgPuFTFdsfORJ84uVyFC00mNbtV6XOZwRzYDn6@LKJgH3i9nmN4dnwCldp1BrbpGWmGuk9PDF/sMPxvgQhRPtk3Op4g@JvauBiLoHm7Qla33TZtc9JuJ3CvaLIS7pinraPYPONxAeVfMEXiA3nygR6NE07ntdGdJG@HiV@L8KMdm92TxNHY90SdIHsMaFgX@H/wHQIHwzxnITmSJnpkpTuTBH3/ZOiMnAFwfVNPxrlm4Qr4wwVszJA@HlNe0kxHkbYS@WYI9ZJE9//t7nvb2siVPV/jT6EYMriT9j8SSGJiJgZM4jMJ5AJJTpYwnsZuQ0@M7XGbP54k57n3vtgvsPt@P8J@lfsd7qv9FGfrVyWp1bYxZObsnn02zwzubkmlUqlUKkmlKj/wdNGfvruo@mklF3i2/EoaQIoYvhpO0hiUHc6ornljdVLM1Hfw/fgeuPgezMeXV@GTOMvSvCqJ31f1o1wCgTImaDy6HQ00neRWewqdFCr2M/QqKXBnFNtsqtcGpjXKWtPZCx3iD9@@xfRmEX9/E/3nd6ApXr9r9wU07NXBmOTNOaxecxxxMjYnzjnK3vAge6ars6y9fce6KC@C/e5AhSA1lgVXD060aWAOaNkd2w1kA/gWnod13BTfs8lcVRJn4DS89NXnlZu7aLvZDrvBOGzndE7fgWtavE8LNpZXd2s4BB0Lvb6s9XI0d3k2laZxEF0yVW5gmcC/9Lyb2UqyRJZ7eKecMWzcTD@kT4lmbPFVZbea1gHLy4vYjr2MsP05GA/GEqehK@EGtRyV@Ud6Ei4@bicI0UFmz7KfVOvNE5/7OdukO8wINm8h3WS4UTcQ4Vxrug@/j0S3t5Q61ylUNb2cSUcomt3j0bwed7jC8KQcRt2NJW9jujvznMNqAiwRYVvfN4VMQYaZTKuVcyHKl7k91u9NyQR843263g2zSnOGQLUlWdKNIl5us37hZbAybtAvNpze0y8AnoajpjCUaRv2tHQEX8Up58HA0Vr0F1LSCYpDRSG5RsPJlTHPlP3LN1tn68Y6W1N1tlJ12hGQrtLJlGmlqtS9gO6Z1wXdsDO6QTojCWtn@pkntulfrx8MsVvxZTlarkS@Wr5crpBAXg6XK/UcCeXl9nJlmx/i5coBP3xervxED8nYWv66XDHDAhmG9MoPL/Bdi3C8t5YrWznvW2YUfA5jU29huWL7lPL8KK9MESIF2k1aI47Yen3dzNEwpImNlUpfgWNiH8sn3ofx@f8S/ScxxzgaERKxx/mAM6uHqpyaNJwZQ@qhacNEu5gxkit6Nq/v7bCZmc2Cah7SGs8tw@BJDV9cTgsjQQypfKJBv4Qg5GZlNkbKmcnuiI6unTiUOzldP1OvwPpAO8fpR5T5OKmEA83p8qa/0iCkA@@GJwrfhOcUOqY6xghnst4MtEDUX5bnNAp9ncZF977bQ7zXnc5E2OZNFuklBuvIdNLh@HAOlQ36gzSTcCouPERuGd6Uk0EJ7p0oxlJBj8wbkvmzbhkEgzv4vXnNccoBtZQIQuJR6VhGmZ0XWBYjKZF1jqYqg49QcGQOjfCw9ZmD@G3rR84n4sbnueKmaciUlSpZcqXFJBUuwGXZRTCS2u3itQ5HZt@3fDUlr7HXkgMAp6StReRr/zv0977o70ahNkSYqGCWYj17Kp1Wr@fOshOYd5NqpzsQib7a9mYqR7aGhOS0OnA083m8NqXiw@RDlHyp1EKf0PYN2eya4Ba6Ta4tBBa0hOFl@uPnFfr4eeVmQk1rJN3LglFaCqhJw5GGW0yTps3HVRo@q4uRwvvbQfe7O3iY7mC38wCPGzCcILmM8uFFj61ckrFNYlu@QKSWK0oEOR@X2m5OPpK456Nbe2xLH/aa@9t7u68/0qT75MkTT8/R4wQ/jFrstdp5XCCzzbqdD2YsW1Z8RNrCYTe24@Oz/nB071MvOyVLRFiTMhBQLYb99Bj3tCxz5PnE2KVyktehqIb1ORkGQUoqQdUJMGVHmq4jIkg4yj0INBCj3hK9fV6teRxTqtnsBedhs8nTl4k@rmcxdI05Eff@vniveBEPOcq2BES7ymTYG4ja3lMfXtUO1eGrutp5t/WT@rj3Tn2o7R7CDcTbd5uvG1uK/q/vHtRVJmWQh@CRWFASXbfDVoiQwGqlVHqsGPJWfzAWuZPb8uT7QXCuXvVbIY6pnsfB@YszeSn0wtGGlKrTcnSMPcyIg4WeRyPYW3B0S1rGQrlp8yVNXLJQlPeE1rTnWPOe99tRJ6K8Gax9B1EYm3t9qhtRD5K8NVfbfVGSEMiSTYc4QC0ssK6oeED5cXZDYAKxvwKJkUMiX7YLShPO/vtuCh7W998cKHgU2drb3W4cNvZ2D9TO3j69vv3Y2H1J9GwcHO43Nt8hiTO@2dtu7DS2avxBECgVFFx9/HoRj@aiUEB2pkrrM06@CwPqfvuW3vWGBq@uAr6uGqvlix6kTxR0o9/D9vJ65iKG@oIrsnxUoHJLtf2X72nOV@FvOOE0R8Fsf5B9F3Nw1aWSes610WDZoPG2rocrTXv5ssfnEedjhfhK4Tq7AMnxs68McDbiaUehym7BRgV73@IphMeyAU0V3SPYAGUMVqqK46ItL/vPGeQG1dbq9uEGVmoTI0L9gqIvjKnJeoYppm1lABTXSBo97AeV1@0H4nv6sKKrHQ0lg3pkP0gG9Vg@QBVtwHZEreocF6O9C4hntSYffj0f7PCxsHpiP2wGvIp9qnGSfuMuDZSNKwm/KV2Ofie7PByhN4hbUcRFYs6PyHDdrgyMUGKSkkyUo0S2baOcWRI2HRw1aLM3ifWNVOIG2AkFnVGsclWvoA5hHBT2Iok7eNoNemIClZjuMO@pp3BSVdW34SMbr48v5gz6zICIFZrGw5bb1lpheNdyVHJzqsZA20hyzFxjgnYbAptTCPwRMAQon1rptHim4hvEANPvaFbOxX3iSOzb/s3NT@zcvmiFqQLaaiv3a/T7754msp9aJxk7RcaOuuj3cEhqJR9ldvpDGuMsVjnCGaRg66w/GEXSh7l0C/jEiac5yo2JjWr7pbqRqg10mKyx1@85lZ4QF99Q6wkx5V1qZY6Xs3MrvpLQ18T5NAmL3R3QCU76l6FzdubjEOkqxPYLKcJ8Vo7Nz/GIMRH9M5PIjr8pRMx9Wt3Y3vyU/9svPsLmiliQqNXG6BD/E2OiLhoefM7HBotD6F16pJlwh/HFCUprGzwtLTHKDTBaB55FtK570Vy3aWJuPP0dl5Ymv/PHr1@rUioPyaRDncdnuUS6@erIVOlzmWOlTUAc2UnIkqzPmS8@w7Ty@gUuKqEX4HOpBzmCdftEMEEtQkzrTi46JFl0TGfd3Ra@pzbYosIokuImw@2P4s@5zerDDa@YGJQoh5w5I6J9A7nseY5ZCs9XU@C254Mj@X13cE/nYifTw3dB254L7btwyz@8GZZMSw6su4P92xywMrn9IbDUdv9mwDJJTkOznG6Z019atNa082v8ZarveOwRGMy92EGxQJ3aLnp8RG2cquekgOeCSRSig8Pt@v6@ysr6hMqS3MOSoa3FIGDfU28Ta9uox8KuYJUmu1i2ypP5krJoM//mDeaZxLtBVGgdxNf0sMIicd3eia5F6umZhVUItr5ngWgol8bui5FB8ZEG/I3WgIRs0mlOAzMzm7kok08Uu0bgmm6@6MauDT9bWMvcjUjJw7ELyLUJCk5xs2R2/30Q/bhi6hEFC/6m0OA2adI039A64YAqHlDGQiHdg3O6xXQpjOxFwV40tIPhVymtYf95hmJGEiVcdGFHrGvlWKMm@vGSUXPYIBHTQABLT50oFs2UYEQ8f3nudqiXTHq59BRESiZi575wuYKKH3/TUxhTw86TVauQu2NtibE5MlgeY3dWw16/OdN92EKvTYqHyapI2s6tKv@PqUpmiVRNhuYzG2MSCfLa6uqj22BPtsIUz/9Z2DKHTMrP0fmA1vcJyHgc8/Y@cW5j1zfpCQPMIZ2Y1psBM1GQVJ0Zc0qq7TwZufgRLrIvRMggMAHCEU/W6qnrCdxmQ5cZyYXOWaba4Axh21AZNVPU/za/OgjkW@u79/31yWBDJpgOfoNV/pv@MA6TW3mO5xznEzwOpL@Fw2GPs8l9pnNAyfE1prmX7fi2nRi8SquQyOdtbks6@naSmN36Zq@BK@HtxQIikGN3b31yey9fXnebutN4XVcP2NNoJ7UXmR1mPUf23It68xBgGcz7Epg@@A7f/bhC/xMOvgFJZOLbfDmmjXcrbkwR0pqPOFSVNgvVsrU82fuduBX04GvFz96PVdb/gQryLmx9b8ebtbNeWk@VJ@TiQS9HpfxsvpDlovQNG7qAlAYhvYnvzoSFmxrGUhLXa077sI/CwVZ4LbtnbDkZFMtPS2vPMty6nj/yz4@eHfsPWtWsosk36J3HF8Or9ufT/tllR3XV4NeT69b499@UWn2sHlFdKz@Iw@fyWrXIHnaf0N@n6lmJOVcj@CPfCkZE7IKEClZqWSXr8PV7yuMHXjRXcENigkvVg3PDhbhiN6qeH60dV3vV0vr5Ue94HZf8Rg@ro4flhzl8@IFmUZIxcjJ/NDrGnOruuoa9SwWnqhySVl8NUXw1hL68CYZR/3Vt92VqNw4KALbAtK03b6hL9PEFWLPh7kmhF17l9DaZr8CxGShImQW@FVSGSwDeT8Z2TDsizKhXfNJm42v@O/YyC6XCxWDU5xTjCROspb5GXzML5hpTiXcUKMtRZPxl4n4BwUny5HAwJF/HYkWdL4u6VsbdSc8BcYSSLA6zn7JZ3CkEovou19FxJi6EQesMSHRJrf7KxdTz5wpvxGpxgXfxYMoRDPnCROkYjzgAoZ8BnzagCtbcY772kaHm472MB/nCe1QjvifDBvIZ1hSRAvNv9YXvN3H550QAIfyC6FwFvcWpNS9SJOXuIG8uwM1ceuGPYwZcq5ROWUBjAVvqqybA2VKcaYRqNZno@8IVyCm0on@6Bfkyv001w@b3JDuThM@p9VsMWnKXctIGfrpJsZxTLG@KmcwOKRZupQZ2umh59CakYTVWW2G3S0gLLRYScuCR7/fq@h/a@uMj1HlskZf0/FR6PpVekHRBKslVoAk@yVRxM2UXvyT5vqlsks2fqquqWHkpUE@3CqSSJHnX5@WNC6N@M0oyb9iuFK60Cc9TCXkn5ecZvS8p91JlLIPb9CNJ1/y9onveYpnK@yJdP34zuoNCNp7VtiYTXFroRd0fMzpSu04Bm2WJmkpJcY7Bqcygquo7mFqckAaHfX4ethvVBMrDspE4PGayG89fZAtayfgxN4mG3GKcGlgzxohDJa7zIRPumi8sUj2cfM8BwTDBaMqM3A1TeKwLjx2wyHXPVCu3IKcGODVtcohXcS/yK/6YwZ5GzuRbnJ24IJhfS@PldnOaQCx072VnkyktTXBdRD7qRs2ZRZK6x5MQZwuJXWcX2NYZyh3sDrbB71k54QoKIymm6G5TNKWTDGXDvjd1IRK/Zf5efJB5GZCOPeiG16qGZUbAt7AyqQvuozAexfC2xY6A4ovBoItTR1b4rvgKtY5hsLKK45YEojOzFzINWPZIfh9P@kI6FSqoPUC@goFIkhBfnJ7iMhluwPavIFqx4xKNCplabywbGjRmHq3INfNQwfkGC@BudOoiIT0noweUjgdBKyxkSEeLSfvJSFM7kQ5dy/vpuDcCp240pVUymX@5iFqft17iPPdJufSo7JDsUh8HlwqPHicXrIhIJmEFfhlXy48zGedsuCVnw3kA9NVrTPTviTfDy7DXCzM1mjE4Y0xKaxwOL8N2IZPZD@0hMOCClXEyiXvY/YthSzZ3SOkKiBlxSzj25TiMOAy/mJ/luLjFZ2V@BodWyWkzdfVl1AYBzY2TTh@nw3xgATcBQg8UOg9HRJQHnkqjxGfPGhfWXc6xEUXUgJ8T52zCkqHXH0Ut6hneycp0CZQcgySV9doTmFB9rW6Ay8GFWQjgekxCAYOAOUqah0NGH5p/Fw5KN8ycsQemZ4ok/fo8Vmi4h8OIpG9CYO4VLubgTh18@KpxoA72dg4/1Pbrip7f7u@9b2zXt9XmRz7jxkE5@0BWr/Zek3Sxp@lyar5HH7K1AyqZ5YRMbfejqv/17X794EDt7avGm7evGwSNwO/Xdg8b9QNfNXa3Xr/b5tN3gqB29w7V68abxiFlO9zzuVZTLJOUU3s76k19f@sVvdY2G68bhx@5xp3G4S4qw6l@Tb2t7R82tt69ru2rt@/23@4d1BUaltluHGy9rjXe1LcLVD/Vqerv67uH6uBV7fXriYbufdit7ys2EnBauVknLGubtIRFTdzO7cZ@fesQDUqetoh4hOBrXx28rW818FD/a52aU9v/6GugB/V/eUeZKFFt197UXlLjMrlbqEL9svVuvw4PSqDEwbvNg8PG4bvDunq5t7fNtD6o779vbNUP1lXm9d4BE@zdQd1XiJrJVRMMohal0/Pmu4MG062xe0hzxru3sHfwqJM/EGEIyxoV3WYCwwwCrSUi7e1/BFTQgTvAVx9e1en7PmjK1KqBCrCo2Dp0s1GFRMRDt5lqt/7ydeNlfXerjuQ9gPnQOKh71GGNA2RowCDjI7EOVfqOW41@IrzkkZg1YzjX5@5UjR1V237fAOY6N3HAQUNzC5Nt65WmeQEekJ1NlKiPPYPg3N1Y6Ux/ugzh83N6R2b2Ho31mLS1t12nGVk7u8omCe9o1nk64UrJTaOZxibSa8plTTs8uThtRr1OH3dMbTHZ@DiPT31Ed/IQGOdTZk6ENL2/wgUWF5vN97UmLXQPmk3Pv0vJFBq3ldDb4PNyebqNiH@BlTc2fioVofvzFKE2ftAHnWyohwMI5BTq/yCmb8F56KlisR3qYri8D8Bm6yiWY5MzHKWQaOTLjojok1TJOxP8Hml24II5A77QamKfFJaRnKkf05/e1@RFJgfnA0ln2e4qFrGIZTSi30NTjVTCLhH4j/ZIEHW4ykIchp9PcyW3Oqz5C6f9fjvneaYM5x3ROvA0591S/CQ8nSienyzPyPKxsw4dEZt1N6sw9vxZk0zpfikMuWU5/GmO@Mcz2IjPB@yaclW8Wa03LXM/SHFYJPlKu7bA9QruZOh8b2p/bXzAaq608nh94vsr@13GFuwF4R2YJrwjLnfMP6@OJQMNMPbFQSSJtIeMYtEpY@xNbOYryniGTFdRG5Y/NFefhTyvE0lIkb0Ium6dmI2H0bWLPcnhl/u1N5vvdnZIdALbx09Xn6ytZ6zbrb/68vsR9bADX/Y6NqB5nPQ0TnJGyRYpPjxSHP/pCfszAxeLyAjf@abT@CP8PFi7jbQlEwQZmhsjvFUPJnrZEHTIKnbAcS9j@HXmyNQMkEs11UNrzoNrVvED0pWYB7QxS3fMvXaNP4Bth78Z4rZBmoE0i7FLY@JcWl2w3MvuGFNRXtyw4x5kKWQNH4sbN0sD3upi@1ncruU3zdtOL8Ziyojxyt3OJQmJe5NYKGNX0ZOR/Zb9jOgNYPYeRl/@qvmNHj9qB3fs7i6IR7XRAZFxx5bEPnWyGa0bfaQhHyOWCZyqmZqeK@zyexopHnt6O9k6BnFGA6OCwDyw8U0DXrd@RCarZAvYF8ue@iKcCucdgLOuOVa/E@fOao6Gsm78h@h345VCCSzr5ESodmXryJgsH60fC0POFJn@FD0Y/j@RJjPgP6cVJ0FPqOU4AbwTJRmq0IqWr0yU6MocNDinGwk13U8fEzDf3I45sw3TpzfXcr@GSKB7Z2w@fGS3h53cDAKAybGx4Y5fa5J2FtDS6UXW08VxTtJrnQ9ySs8VZqqYgptfO/ZZ7fLN2QpePOXJXpNT4Wsqql7Iwu2ERz0tmSaW8up@nBVwnvH/UXzAGyB2wDOXnonV6iRnlfQoM3JAu1pyJpy29ZhEaum3G0/tHijHRWZK9uuTL0MoAr0BfKbbyUFd@krMc9MeF3kmVofsBQ9u2rFMxuSjXdadsCFmNwSc@23eDEHcl9EVJoiuQGdXfQk0lbvPhiKoJLE6TPwMQtx6BSItT6tXFnvemQSHWuzf9SRCQCi7WiZHQRx8aAzd6/IF9SYYE8rduzVbWKz44KDvw3YRlcm2hC6PGDetfn9IqmOAdhOOfjT2CuqD3nQIe/HFUPsvpPksGuodCaP0UzVQm2T1ztOMuOZn1OJohNsK7QLzBzfpPISFqLgnuc6vqRwxr@HRDbPpGF0/LKvc8yTlOdGE3ZIyEZ@rNfX1q@QSgmqXoSFTMIrt4oJtNrkenDvY4XfVH37G3A8VqNcO29YzqQOS9wKlkxo99vHYGknTB/2YdzSoK7ADYilRlo00a6hKc/QTzU7arimbeMeE71JuyffXY5nUWEtRRQnj6tqJ@dby1Jmg0op2DWqdhZZXVhmVWQuubzcuxthbaPrYWmU/9axIqYgSUb1vVEc8idy0Tx/xpDf5q/djjB76gjNurYICYeisOFedlnOMH2wKPkThsO3uiZIm0w4G2H7jpU@/x7xotg61279WMIrDMa0AWsXousgwmrm/9M96za1@NziN@lFA6zT41b8WiYfHMT@iw06H/auYwzdJTEonU3ucPIt/GXHDhnd7LrnuuOaKR@Eg55opjIbj2pm4ieCdcxgBJjFnmb8Hkz7SbJnHq0mhTPr@Kdvjlb31G8s@Ks8qLCf6AKAF3MaEBYXcIR3xxSTn8un6VIaTeRkcHE9UXgXeDRZ7KYyfEYn4GCaFsUFmyizBbQRWZjdifNS@9tvsg3AIR0vhdohAQ3GOP/sBAnmTFPkRlgIVVX5acorKKco1/BDiYXwzuVee/JOxJwT@BPrlR7O4ZRYjsIjrGG9LsaxXtJdRwoXNAyOW0SyJSYpFp1HPuX7IUT2uJ6Gmk8c3UYMtf0gp0m72prgSIzJHCx9EGcw1SeQ0xx4mlWW17LHfDqggtVGudDPDhrfZz/LgxyGu7JxBMG1pyDkH6ZtI1SIqIVDyhHmti7L4VL59xKys3LXXJghYnWVy5oTszmWN5sI3UCKZX3Gs1R@SMM5OUE@beizHo/5g@Y7Uu1F2zPTMNovWLc@71RBYmK1Kk@WDNpO2OsbjeD0zic8E06QpxpZmxENYvvKzZfNJIl5Xmxhv1eb4FjrcRLPEbspOKra/2zL2MSlewqLXTDR2SDHucFK6br8fNanhzZsliIYpy6smS4wmREZzLI8OqAkyWSrdnULMfRr3CXq0iXKot020c/vnRqJOGskZl6cmKeXkEvSE43Zc2iS5NOjA@AJu4kTDtULKKpzX/piP8sr5EzgZRoIAhFYc5pN9KNnBTTprgo84OkAn14S1UBmSiJ42XAsH6/TfEoy98uvNHW3x0Bzny8frAunaQqJVBeeaB8ncN6fXo@Y1Q5kiBQ3xGaSwLZqSTWd3b9WfbQvlIwhSmpO1pW/JR2M89ZCwoT9uUvMaOnBSlS6ZGlHpgdBk0UBjgVYpp91QlqvQ/qKhcDysG/QwogWEfM7h56EuAXfeayVLbRS5bo@RxdPkltHmqfyGFEkYSt5Bfj0URdXlhSsBCAVjKl8tEwS4NWXscSjArndczkshqvuIClbLGJb0kb2iJnaeM9JBVJ3h8aqTozQrxzMXRn4mEFIsZudJECGdZXaWBApNdDNxcXI8md2eJAcpxIb3heLUFbpX0jS0PScE5EDfJS@RKEdl5Zc0B3Pi41UvlWj5m1OflZzU0mQq0cdieJQvT6Y@LaVSU9WurKSLpkoSPTy31lQikcJzEbZS4c/946sprstzaxPqLDJSWoa2z0Ygdlpl0rqt8GusnvOlbKNjGHjuzXCz/GpKiJWUU/b5DtjVMh8ZwHf7n26tsUw1mOhYAeyXzlx2ycmCkDXWLKZ6NAsrXeNpzzooMGvafke9P9zZSbl9PRkbQ6PzcLhaKpXAxCeu83tjW42tpKhfTOcudi663eLg6i/D9ydFlv1hyCEBKmYFHVKX0KCIC/3hqUSGAA6UFbnz@iIr1voXnY4bggEnlOg86jbJqb0hKJ6AImv08v6QN4AYpJ5gf0ED0b5flB19V4EomhqKOYai0jAJvsya0zMiDz50YJ9tT6oYGASzsWaiecurbnzBDILIJtxZ7L7Y@5KYJ2dfhd1u31cfEAAangIWvk0W2NlxC5QkC04Y@XbvRcz@aH0VXkZd514xsri8DnBmYjJxJoxfePjG3w9P69eDXPbo5yxNK9Tkh2jmQ/in9lX2NOtpZ/F3ACt8SGjfKfd5MMi1mE6TmWmq1yM4eSKMHpX9mWufVBaP98Q0zW7PDaLORrfAzhqo6R7rAsaXPXcvt@SG7Ja42U/X5Q5oWBIYGif4XLlbCVw1@@eJxctRp3M3qchhAKRjv0siSiSUPycQ@QyAR6AefkRPeNH@KU/DemfCoYgoOAjWMS13UKCJApnM/Vb1t6tcrVZTS4OHD1WttkkP@byqbdbUNj5sbqptet/E@w/VldXVdZG5294X@rhpPn5TmwSDdzgfts6G2/RKaVXcG4O1Nrp4qVhd8teXmtXnG@tx8ai2iWv99PSf//Zf//Pf/1uxpl/@B142@eXoZ5upUCgUl1pfln74to73o@3j5aWTo6XB8fLpOrjs7@w1vN8Y5YPEfLQwPMksyizgfGU7UrPOZu8zuqgywQPPg@Fnki4VtdiKi4v6ayyRo1jGLrZC53uIe5QntIQ3QQcml/KExCIBHWM7nnqnFcIAj@YboiThAjtQKS9nK2bjHu5gbAZ7qrKoPfGwznoZ4k5L4kkBd3FpxspHvTjsYQf8knVeaV4mE9BvNGpq/i3@/CY@3exfqwefcupBST3w1YNsln/Ka8/oq7dUjHA7V7LRciCb9SklOVqAmaGKI1b0eP3AsXYmyJ3JLHHIHkAybio4s9yC8@3qjy/LSMC1@DSzgNimSrZI@JAJRRa/LPW@Ubd8oRzfsqmrNqwoNPUqhitzTlRs/0IFCmIxBEhqPheCVPpUJU76@EYynormi@7rDEcTYsAg6/7LHR73@EBz0VJP2zyn1lIIc8Tm8/IVc@O6XIZmtJEi9ScI8IGKLCdLfJNweXE5I1beTiu5mXIL222fZj6xdRiHI2ObLoX@phwmEGtul3BLPX2vRRtyy/GKykb2eMWpKjtp@60yTpHzi@4oGujrClw7BtQXW9s3GUnoUQYkcMRnf2V6hPFGgfEUNdEtEixrrNp9NF1GQk9fTacO9gpycuQQofhzjsb214mx7RX5lohhB@EBRsqa8nWCqBtrrytDJvZpMDxBdMCgwwHVRnJuxvt5iFE7gXG/Y5EuMGQ2OU/GMzVlcTAMTs8DXy3u9g@HwbhB0xZpPqNWwaMWwgUTkMDg01XPap5BWFqku4QpYpvClkMIXtAd6/Bo0rdZe@cEXWqGgna7gkGQYiemZPg11VcTdEy4@js6wUV5Snjb00gtYlnywtJIQ8q612Z4mE0NnYypwR07duBkM4KqHZmGF3ShC0y053zwS5K8Cx8Buu6svgWoryKsPUP9mJ1Ow16QmpwG3Yy56F9cVzIvYjxzKEqxRspoKE/KScQ7YEV65M9pLxAyNxl3RpmFXG7hU6zDuS268wg7@ba2@MVARTYAHQcw45sh6l0vEmE5MUMlMTAKqsGW/wSh0w1OCb/xVTAGK35azP14r@gd/fypd/wg96n39dPvHmOiRbKZZfNqUR9mG4mlxwrNjEU/9Wqs0mLjavBTL53hU0/JHRaHBIRIMXf0c/H4a5EQ@rToeQ@KnxaFIKkuAybF@fUVAb44heZiGoviYmbBe@CZzs/9WPYUza38iz6UD578EhZmUcnb9LTOGXYIFN/T/e1CrpzExacrpccr5ce0EjoNr/PD8ALzbT6@OAmvSZWIsZylqefT7yluSBHi23UcrNPHa2qnhDWRuyexvqSkRage5lxPxrIVlSkIT1B@ojK7S8UVF8/mCXD4iAW/r4jlTF72BSWmgw735TB/xv1z1BPEkGuTt0OEI2FlIDYivIWaB2QTfOUmDvXMcFnme04FtQXfrQyEure46MwWvX4vr5U1r7C8DiUat2a6T0tPS5NjdGqIpkboklamlu@p8saPT/7jv@/9tjha3FgpfhjS72jxt8W1p4vySA/09si8XS5uLD5HtrVvi@MirYHp8cl//E8qv/EXgoOU8XP6s7FqYK2NFzfyVS7ydXFjjR7KKytU7//613@lNizJig2xWJeavmLE1g1FtoIe8y6lqwZaKcvS5USs8MUswBALQ1qb0wsMo65XnpZ4m25RW1VchtrzlbFH0VM8G2aN2FRIdjKMPQVpRlKgigryAtKYUHSUY7thzDbAvAma6pf7hbWYVgC/aHMOW6U13bgfw2RoSZZF1IE5qZHW8/KwUfoxa807KlljU7JuVEgs7bSsffpondjhbT8cRa20lYQZruet4Co8KYAPC2H7gtZUvbjb/3VYvCSWPC@vPC12sLlfZDvu4oAh5Qfjwu@kCOpgQLQwZKNTXw2pB/rncOHlc7QgUuh37JmUiSdJWvYgbMkeVjomMWWRO36@HA@jOYVElc7xX1LgETlTB4J0YqV96lHJvf2Kyj60GSUfr3k9YPOWjWO1C4y8WMMOWDYVMtwG7A6a9hRqw1O@hMSl4HVdshSCdrsZ6LRcZiFrQqX5mYWzsDuoZjvi3h2@U3FioukvauaNUPIRdhDyeRZ0gHUejgJaolez/AXr8aQGuEnRZ63WVVxC1o7Oq1f17SpHXZlT9ZVUfUU9Ci0hqcfyjOONTbnZRLZUsVU5DJs4UptZMdUWm6DNwwL/AINYuqXRwbUE3Ry@AUlUS5qjrcrcbvN5LUw8chXKnT3ZWpTI1ZnF5PKjb3LIDWroTqi3IJWRgIAX3AoslOn9QG5AVE2Y0aiXEX9@E8nGv4cGw23YgytR122dOB@Vaal3idg30YjvUioigfYr69pgZ2T2sKCtiy0bgjaLjZesB5bqVHixxRlNd1Q4DLRxCZXNyj7VUUvZ8LIdHb1WAkXQh2ypvPLo8erak6fPEOVsQbd2NhgUKmAVMDgLCAZr1DlaZON7tZpdzsonhKCerhLQZ4HFARzMuq48z7h9vvLuVcslDayUZVhXHEZDiuvtSgaZQByGBcwItEbJDbO53I@VIzTs@FPb@0r/E38b/4DMcMYdbSCkd/rhbeKZKnMuDgeqLJjZKU7uETyoeDrFzRv2O/vwNhHC1lXYnip6DQ8Qo7Nh/@L0zOWOgnZtdUgDhgjOfqmxgnoZjhIHYw5W0EX1hkPDuX1RNfCOplsAo1xMCdD5BDgNM@23MtCWphgdyzQJwbMmbqziCNExHXXZmbmz11f13e1JxBbdMHQMt@BatpJyx57M4EAGsXqd5h4SdbW3C75KqmWSn/KqzAKuhHxlvg4f4K50C4GoHaoYWc16wyg3jyxl5sXEtWlSlPoReM2AWS7dTkpzr9W0AgQxglDvJlkh5tvzHJdkCU5uJ2OcgpezFcdG9E0Ux@xgTleW9bRFKWfiqAILmRsAYt@mlJWGlCroUX6sc@Bl6W0Ec5Rb0dga0GbIdqUazszJYSbY6jYWB9iIOm5ogfY3drd8tV2nPzsftn0oypu1n9BuG@L5ZnzLGt9yRTV2TBe43mLZ5hY2U7/hihIxS0k7jE0QhPDtSFTEMPEaUG/saNrLoD5Kje3jhCvAroFWws3uqB4kcPTCeyALevFuXXHwdR3@VpHNq2lJY12q6GEhW1zzB7ZDk4WkVgtJSHkHECuTIKyjloTbFxKGFwt01rwDvXYxjN3Ymc3TKZaVBRWp7TtFInuaZ2@kzDy2WNFssVJBP87jC@bbubxxEnb6@i6aZY5beOPeH@ON/N2ZI///BXPU/znc8Uhzx6MKZI9wh3Ubzjc6OQx7fwbHnIx5Dm62o9MI@0Md5xWNKPkOABZ4wBB3SCmxXELbbhAnKjc74eHkfAQjoZVVXAz4Q41/rBv/uAKZy4/b4f@rjc//gxu/qhu/WsFcM6PntWrnuFv/x7Q4UQlz6Q8zuxfqrmTz/mhL13RL1yqYTWd08//1lub/D7X0iW7pkwo8JsiBg7ivn8/NoonUDrYajcTcopDRTrtyiGM/mys9rL3a1SwtHjrdi/isCm1d/WH8n2r8n0Ia8RPC0OEswtqG2rW8LE/lsrxolrzLoXDJSloi7TWe0Z326gkrWY/oCUqENG9sDfVChRRyXxKT06ZCoj8m0tdOPnfFWWS7DpaJg3NnAS0rwrKXDHHRfHWQzJU1O69ssw9ktXW4//rhfxEynAef9S00Qh5dexV2u2YmcZdgh9brlG6M0xzAPtBrjhSraHIysiN929uyy8LNUo0dW0zMi7MXCXLUhvM/WkudQ99wonJjy4hoU9DlzaoKprlmeSFfqO2SaXaTdYv/EJc@01z6rKL29cLgJlIFesNP82KyTltZXZ03B0ipAn4wAEs@5Z8zqv43)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/8x2yz)

[Source code](https://github.com/mousetail/Fish).

Console version:
Build: `tsc --lib es2022 Fish/src/scripts/interpreter.ts`.
Run: `node fish.js polyglot`.

Mousetail's ><> is mixed with ><>/Gol><>.

First the code `/8a7*.` is used to jump to line 71, column 9. First executed instruction is at column 10. CRs are treated as
newlines, so it is actually line 66.

Mousetail's ><> is separated from ><>/Gol><> with `-1 % 2`, which is `-1` in Mousetail's ><>, but `1` in ><>/Gol><>:

```
e        ;:n@04+7*aa\ 
          01-2%1+  ?/383nnn;
```

`:` fixes Chip, `e` fixes `:` in psPILOT.

Answer (score 1):

## 384. ><> ([fish-jit](https://github.com/primo-ppcg/fish-jit)), 16574 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 |/183nnn;/283nnn; 
_|/1000 |/01-2%+?/123nnn; 
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\;:n@04+7*aa\ 
_+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn;
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?4|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0-<?MLot ~<p>3:s4oya 8:nd=5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1997*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6yfX@uC/SmXogA5kh8QwjSq9NznjyM9xAAqL6/720r8GJ6zzgJ809OfhIQyJhQ@tKLn8RK3psHrVkJzZRS@wmHZGHsBcXbMM/lg4eYnDQ3T@Ij8okTXtq4El6/p2cSW0TkqnV1HyZ7eAnqCpMzVCa@FW9MtfZFyTWYJvn/iHzSkW9ZBs1JlZE5h/zD1VwczXSABgV4EKhmHSiss0J@GwGR9QZfRGFXTCaWQNRXs1nwCYrUWUdVf8QP@Rp8/zp4dOD58d7xy@eNzKtS/@Qf1AK24bUAlUid7I9EQrv4w04dq5UnpRLWJAcfa0FZ@S8oFwMvwC1XLTaUtEWhRJ3MM7muW0rCuk5UKRLyJ8k8tTIF8cdcOKwgxJTBfkqLipc5QBpToA64qBFShMqrcIyqxIe68B9btq@/9UPppEvflCvgp/Uw4R9PeDQbgeO0/NT9Ax2@xWk@GDv8NGLZwcsyOCi1ZyZvcmwVs5zNfFc9wrUU9@kjZ81FvejxKGuarX4gzggJi7HWYU0U5CKdmjoECzADuq08GNvscQmwQcMxsNKUf7zN5TLuIxnGJIQNh5kKg7JQpunhrKxscGOoZGw@88OPzl4xjD/B/fJGVGEINgxHov/sx/3@EdOArVVwccE3RGxiqT2R4iqxgj0RSxUWiDOqe@O139SkD4qQoojwq@ZhJ9jEgT62A202zPSOHlFG2GSFITxTyD6yiKDhKgJBR9GwOUyVPzoeuzU9ExUW4F56KMexuXGjjvsSPeozPbwe4n4VUadvrgDWZ/aE67rzNd4FIOWJoc0J802KbP8@zxiJGB8ewMae8cAKYJ5tgk86aTCXkNLxCWpCldrIkn1@LUoAegKmSTkPCMBrylu9JSmq7z/tX@iDKoMzBMwf8c3zzL3wPYrvq0P5l/l5pcKNrTrih4XeYlmCJWz@iXgGQnxj7iPfCbS5qpkFohDfZQBYWXmCKrplLCOwXkK/CkBPV7ASTQ@gUqD5gY15quQ4ekZbiuB2mErioJNCiVbmQ7wGDO@m/aKlthCvpBTFcikdBoApM86DFBNAAeYTFagmwin5rj2CqSl7e1tJuL0llErVHnNKpv2y6z4KszoJoQVzoaYuQaDOBBlEQP86n40GH1SahKjIvWKq3EkXD0HhiXyx@EL7baPCJElAFkcRwZ@J2CGXxSdANPnazvu4Dc4I5/82fQBSSqMSWRKioKvfOWJM4HmA5108VEvrnwFd5PzIRDViHr8O7ukZBjbo3y9Zy10BgTfFvL7mow0gIPKZq6OptG6FT9FEM8RREVc1XwbL1lz0rRbCm@bDJrpD1c0ZhvMv6wM1rRZXu696ypmE1cVxCKy2O5z28F5vAdQGJbQFC2rqIXkoki53Moi@SXyk4HioB6rC0gOyBSQjK5hvnbG3t7@weHHR0@fX1OjSiHjV4MB3a9vp5qSnG60QkM8WqzlKrn3QHn@@N6DoCIWmS5EqDEQfr8k6k0lWUzPI8jFca@rRVuVw6ulW5/jT7lCiKv5zWo3ZY0iXcuHmvkS6dKRC@kBHZy8mrhWWoWtfP6mLC3gKRHQ@/zU@7WsJpLnl40WMNF2LH69JazoCC9j8hZ2AjA1va1NBRv79cJhwcIvYB/jtwW9aF/Mru6L4mYWtfSh0o2Jc7LQY@g7RDwi5Q2SARIpyEoQdG3vO@JM@kLbpsa/0M3V@0WVl0UyXMjchPEIqOPgY99IRRa6gn01uUPdG1pmRwiUxnF1uYFWz1BTLlf4lkgK/hdneMIJ//Pfs8pMpv2ViSRSO4KVZjdp3g3gJQXo0MjdPZ16Q/bUGfMvENA@mvtGYHrmAPm9P@Xzbgb7eDqCcH16PTNoTRMotwSRAZPxMKuclwIq4SvenaVQtTGk10D1u37B5VEvn5gl5aEx65kDoO2JZBoo2h1VbbFQOS8WmpTx2nGR6mxRCzd2xY9Ql0EU7V9KQ/NskQG9ocum3TNmifhZPFlpQfroHj/79DSeFFe1JdIU7atO7l1VGR1mv6jeTEn0id87A33Mq6hFuXydSoDbVcBcdWHw@bNyWR56An3Osoac@/OJ@wiMwEYk@iN9zBJTm6t9lBlZE82EnSZ9eFKdq5S1WSpFAhW8yENmFLNPJj5@J3R7zhJKDb94Cq6e3cPXW3PMGqost8BMiSTZJn6WcB84LlSEmhRACIYoFQJbwyYEYgbkiHcSmTdwiIP@EBZepDxzhTd9pY2WfhzECZWa1e@yyGcmlzlHsVyu@BW6TBXLDFrfdXIoKwD2Gp0L@HrArq8RCnAG4q8sxBaE/DrFi1G6MZ6Rh74qKchOLKIGOtAwxQDWQklzd@jinTiwoa8Af1CpvDh@0C4lFZGFKqkGrtnDpUn@JYNQxPO/PQXdVFkKGq9yie4jjIbKP9tc5xXqoHxAHUa8QlJjUTT4CpQDYdlbtE1VvbHV@xH9WoCQORwA/KO77QAcKmwN5ixX@K0m9j/7WQyZjcSmqp603dNUPJ@pwkOt5lme3dlsStJmI1Pb3dRBipq8mTVBJle2cvdPjWG/dzhQmqLIsiynKFvn5@fxB1tPzZd5VpB6plZ4M5tfZgvZN7PLrFp6czJWCw35zawllmrpkxZ7@vSzd@13SXF2On8jNhNabP/oQlRzKPLHKmV2vlPIxk7KIH5CuoydsLdwnfQZ/sn8thcx62ju9EGEjYss1mwCxlWxKCpKI96CP4n7r@Dign@jLtflnda7d8mGrk9mc2aa5tjr9eB2hsBBasnnDOTlu0DpeQSFNelNEhReo1n/@nxCnrHZnjEYTA/0uoanuuXddnVuTh9MHn/@aXC9wOvts0i0t/53kFOphCQ1VsxTVNp6PoZfVP6zn2xcps@ftrf/7JsjxdjA1xG@vnP5GM3P1fydjY079@7lcmlN07j56edPf3Fvby93P51/2sjv5KTMxvaf/snGhqZta8pGy/PUVrxxcvKZqGVyovxnP4q3nz79uufVs//nN97VVXwU4XHKikAn4MoyFYz4LMGtIo/1oVfsbQxauRqb068dC9zPN5ha3yn@l@8dvYlNYnVN@dSF9yT2JlYoxbgRDGDLBrbTWD22jcEKl7G5UqvVwFj8L/8W4tc/BjjoM9@GRz0fwCrMY3WpRlEuYvUCGFRNg3T/7298I5JDTiZqxMYF1y5rwCXmipq404Jri65tAVV9ShlFCcLZk@HEcJhauqveRYsJFnjZBn4zwZg0Y/hNeXa0y9izRiqVasltCS75JU0SKaqqNVX1LpAD6c5WrSZtMa7MNJvN30WF7Ema0ho4MGIadz/9h7hiqxyrPze4Z0KssLH76n69DmXK1rNb9RRdfkeiPlUsiY6zK7I0exUHEaTRevWIcQ3MdTFT0sR0Or3bJvsMcSXNwpaEF3/GYqELdll21W0pCgTxXWNfPlzsAK8//9/@/Pt//j36fZ/u/4C6UO2e2Ve2INApdIk6XLuVSrdeF@uueN5Eex3aUaZSqpSU9mUzsQUUqPWMqZmPLuL5bPw5/967ylgzSbHhomTrfvJor8cWznXuUo@6@R48MDkwvxRkWMIamUOsXQsHQ6u/a1xqnNZbEjJENamhFvIticeqB1eZNXahmkStWBZbdS2vHbHd9oxfbLjpMScGkmEhwKOf3/qibPXQZ2GrR51i9SBafRHmy4YL8yvEGg2lZdCAELix3Y3KRqlSqGhKu77@gqYZtVJQwzCeerHTWHhxzMYWCI2FTfOqW1AVoYUFLZh9mXBQWR8y2U21lC2oYtU3aW0mVqGRaFlJG7TFjCqGvQ3n9@HagB/94Qqt@NwgF9@Zgly/NlhF3dKySv5O4UDD8fWWK5pXAcYJ1u10Om@7HeA6dL2jd3V1ok/1mT7XJ51pZ9aZdKddhl1meUY/6@SdkjNjM/rLUiybVzdjd6lRv2tssGecCrVYKriaqVuvF7Lc9o1kcPCWJGcWE2L/AFdd1VS2BeNTBh7AlJERZGb8qarAYsBonbfebTXebUEHrae2iTi26pKfS3jJ7d1WSrq8bIC5WvX/2/XQWKWLm6BwrctUavtlHbiPl/VGCkC@9EHKEiOgcrve2iafMDE/Nd97uwX8i5TabmzXnH26ZeogUgsgbi/lcnc3JYNpF2LWN0GATW1K0gYOiQ1/iICgrXoqKAwmnQAm4fz8Q@54zokXnN0VXiDmQR@@3L6sXza2Ly@3t@G/Tc9L/w2ul9vX/vRaXGvCLPxbSFiaDaXeVJo@qWiBXVbq6CIrTTDU4Q3hGlmt1GqgAS659d/mX04vnqELZrklQ66F2BbbiqFezmxsS4i9ev/F/4J38/0Xv4/cIoOfURFi59iplS2UNctc5IQHsx/b7DG/bDDjHVjRBR0e19HR5g8bl6MU5ZXMKnzGP6GWCkkZh9@202@jqg@ZvYKg1ygfE7VSQWyn1LnGYttioUjE7heuXfF4/B@90srFOJ@mQV0VrzzPexzJ5SKfELiqZVRJvajzzzHwL@f8wqrrH/3CukuIXZSZUQH8JBhHjBCDdhRTFEmC4aq@PcLDDLhQIqFMelr7THqxJ@Ekij6hZbAunyCoHR7UyuU6X@PZfEqdZ@v@FjxV@B9sQDFYsw9hm/1adwTsb7OfzWtN1N0fkzpv8PfoLf7YcRd/z97gjx2/xd@zCf7Y4w7@jt/gb6@Dv@MR/u69wd/jt/h7McBf8yvZrFoVN88JMym1rF5uzkTCUDW2U29@ZeLOK5ZhN8xey/8sVTZXZslY8yvGrGuMJxXu2I//9Lvf/Ga8VotLcfrYT051XKYmYwwD4hdLGUtWoSbUjAol9OLV3fhXGiSi58utBgZpga8Qq7FNdVPNWJluRu2oHTCYLOOyzDAzVHsqiTIZg2XmmTnLjBy1ByYDfhkwmZk@ywxYxs7YEAx8wTRpZyZo6sNrAL8@AHLhZ@L23Y6a6TJIyEKmjj4lqrYxZuai3RQaLM7EVwbIorIqZ@SC2cIPMDXEV6@aylZLK5eYjM1ObjdeNeMtsSmiUn6tnGOdubHRfCXC0J0RefNEFxbzPBBwqzGl2VQ4JgFJhOjLy3b74Mn9dlvBYar52Dla/I@ORlHrjf/RkfP4yBk58D86OoLOZdRTuymg47u7NaDr/msnVq/uNCs0LARDQ0zZ3mnWsxKaCykg@hq6pb7ktYAI7/pGU4ifgYBxBrJJNQESyln1tFo9I8On3AqGNprRMfyf@Qb/TRCqoXxzBtcpgSUbGs8@bYYmblA@PQOnTxnIZeEfBMCo9b/C3/xv6//4BUuyRKOVTJxfbifoSuIvmTy/PL/0n/VkIuFbEtvwQwewY5TzyzoaKdA5mBqJZCt5ecnd4JlIbnOAdUhmu05xF@Fg4IiFSVKy/JH4r/uGpP2rGa8CX8xl73yG@lFMrDJ9se@m2ZxlMslqJ/jeCK4i6xe0uSFZpY9NbnYaautPf0TflNlJUqB8rlpVtxi3aDmtWs0FtmKpWi0Fls1Eonz9qmd21ALIJ7lcMlmtgmUnAJsBK8RtsHcpVmNNeLbu3uWJlLSLiwBmNldIZXC/U7UapJSHZA1P7/o0@fzwiD7HAqQmH8PvIHFSksjQx5zwg4FxsSLevZvoGbhHvLezl7x7VytnLi5Cl/EYnNQlp3a7Z7rtNrpnLy7Etkj7ZMp5sGdKFxdqppxS40nHTTzBL01CUglJZXe0OqVaBkqv5Yrg7Wcgv71dyNXrhRy4FErxJK65cxIP@Y2L8aoYO6cyqKUip4BiFZ2j@4egL@M4wc4vY1ShLJdPJoCQJoFLvIzhz0Way0ekfD4JmLkUeUi1XOZBkyxXSJRSZf9X2wCpHdgg/kNeLpvKbRW3doEnxp83W3UhTa6eGzX1snZuVHDW/bLa9b/ZjSpNjLt3s2VAUSlTbQrt9v294712uwZjGbJS8EBHou4Canpx45XqLtWrWsozqEDuKMVhSGAlwLKibeXVEmJFMPuooghwIHDxaYNtCBq98SGUOao2wBHkG0itBxfrsQ4b4MUGKM0xk1l0MYtxf3p2u2Egh1@@b2iluCTwBS5GeAl@t8vyNgmj9tNHe/sHx2ltW2Ix7cHeflp7/uJeTEVrfmEn7yzanx3s3T96ARGePjrYe37w0eEnBy@egrvHzhZXQOX95@IdNa2wn7FPhdfuW90wdGNqGO2z6fTsDXttmm0Tas@aQqGcgcs8ow1lGeuLclXh7pqe/vq17o7pYu9/@O33P/zv3v/Od9//zrff/873f/rF978N94/h/i5/f/fflPP4/OkX/@x33//274Djf4D7j@D@yU@/@I1v8Jvsfwz3f4q4/bF/R8LxWwBYv/LTL773o59@8as/gPtf@vcPrt@/9pPV9/e/tf7GeN/73ZvDfPffwv17HFYQ9ru/zd3wfS38b/Nwv/qD9//i3/H/n/o/NP7O@3/xx/jwLf/0B3/6n95/899rWulP//X7b33v/be@@f5b33n/rX@svf@Nf61moo/fff/9P/irP/y9v/rD/5H@P6bn733I//0P/ulf/K9/8b//xR/690/g/ndg@slf/HvoKn/7Bz/E//f@4G//6If4/5//1d/@wa//7a/8T2T4TW74f/7lv@HPv/61//g3v/Wdv/rJN/7m13/yN7/5B3/1f/zq//Ub//Gv//vf/@t/8k10/M2f/NUf/cpffvPbf/mtf/6X3/xizfPbNz6/@AD3L/4BXD48nx8C50PK9WVdvvi58vP3wcYiFWgn0Lp/@f1v/BI08H/B2Ptv/xhP/8G95v9jTaUwP@a2/w8YtOtlRp8MmOD@9fff/i6i6H8AFME/xNd3QsuSD7d8Z2EBtP7Wiki//NMv/vmPyBYzKnVaxsHBuqSVUlsg0GyVy/6A7a/wQJRfWoYWAvBT@g5SqCW/7yBte//Db7z/0T9@/8PffP/DX8HRWsqV03tpSb1leQwC5j8gHAYsfEg4DPgZpN9O0dSblPoMbOwz3/Ozzz4T2hcKHjPdvQDXz8iJX4x74TFU3yvwQ3c8l8rAvfHqVQvXVBduilrK2rZdVTT@Zr5XhmFCknYntaOomu9lXCibHBKrgku2lG1WK/ZuJpcqbul6M5Jv1Y@7oTBVT2e3snpa2lFyPA0hlsLipIiZ2QqYq3yWzVJ@SWeMLxyhOwSabZFxhk9yRe@ZgI/Ff2GcCSxFs8l8TSO1MJLBj@cnwY1CHpJJzcLlKuL2GGe3trgLrURTurkywxLMZqkZiNFggBRS4HUPGPpaLYURazw/YOVZq5cYZSWVqkG5MTaPk26XEMTsHkGBmLXUM9beqs14xBTCqwfoSAno9ExUNTFVqt2HBGuz@wxhIXAC@@pVrV6qzeoI7h3HR2qWukd5QmC11Kz@Duw1ggnxhNj9d5CVUi2VqpcwQSwkr550m1dSngpHZU@xlF8H8MYDBTu7jN0R1ZLIlyE2EGE8ND5Ti9AYEIKDfzO15ReH/oGR7i1C@AYl5afCuP8OMbs7nP/FAABXkmRZZnDjCv8O2wXvGQeVomThleIQUtQiqAWEDgxnmFJCiuo3RRZIP1bb@tIXAsPCbG5uCrG6mBWPZEKdojD3pEKnK3DDIQooFSYWyiI6G3TUJMgLxK9S@ptxXLqLMw6Y3Unxe3d3i92BYtJ74SYwKZV1ck6MQ9lOpUQN4NedlPASBBsB2ikBuhDkWY2WClNCOs2YXIuhHzs6OvIzQQ4va0IKmrmWVdGOC1bT6TQGMWQ5LafT/lumNznIvkEmX/8tbyJy6WPuTNNyVZC/gHaAE4sKSyoI0ej47t07qBXawVU5BPGV@Zu5tFyJPMGBq@@xrHlwJknLlQUu2zO1kGMsQdO4cCUZHr5JQENKCnznP89GcCXiWqkUp5CAfzmxFezuK6jUIHAWN1bHrAYXFytL@WTguX/E9o8ePz54cjxutYAk0ufpjfbYdbqG5yXQb@/JfX7qQysXkrFGA0EfVzQkMcJBJYMJpQ7vPzt8XmG82H4lJChjVVq79QtaVoXYePzpdszf3STiFxYd8Tk@K4uyJbRyFqLG6kKsa6CwgovyKERXWVV47A3uOTOWyKRFMa0WUFhM4hIk5OMXnSlD/b9cWRD0KjwLIm9vEwaE@rlECyRohPoqCPW6vy@QqUL9@cExRDg@YqqWkYX6Z2wmY4LSpVC3apZhDybDTdxgJzYzYqRMm41MGn9aNgtPNVdIq/lia2PDOpcwzSZV2znulLwE67mExfgqXEz4qsC@Ck5wQRq4/ZH5e08Pj6r@BkDUtJfguwBFNQ8dLSngdDkHJ4yjF4xCV5abhNjG559PWL0OMrp0@ECIAb0YsmAPnGT25KFM1dybugb5DhjrmZ@Y@OlMuWd6Y0ufQ@cBbMQuLy/7AOnwAdPqGll5jB4@L7vk0gHz5UwXYnalUnun5oqCdlKpvMtqmgAOwpaCm@w2oAHQXoUthf@qHiSSzZYUoFWqKMIrm80KOP8sCBVDYLQf5V2mVpN4G8zmVNqOIuDXWPRZTQsvP@zsziJsNsPDog94sMHEZZnAr8j9fFtBIBsgDXfg0be/q373zNy9m8WJkGwuE854UInZJdTNZjaXRYzjCadWLFf0l2JEUWzFBMuYsF4NzLEmPPiknqbGRIY2JBvZUkaINWIN4f/vl7/atD2uZzPqtjIGow7G3Laig7EDxvy20gGjCcbytmKCcVrPqpltZVoXmLDNlfQy1AFUEyfGDHWCczex7hlWX8aDTzWREtDEbV/pfT2IWO/Vek53intOqj3ZtG3DxRP7PEIuJ1YdG9VH1lCRDOk4YInkuTConZFeAcGoDWTUSOTauiX05I7Tm8veZG7hESLLcWtxYEHjgccCugEsDE687WSzuUqDteSxM94RtHwx1VAzMPbgrZbSWnrD2CkWKz25axm6u5Ov5EvpHp5O8pfgdvKZykD@7PGjh5PJ@JlBR5Z2cmWIgDr8UNvWTqmSz7caDVFMNSiZFn6vnNM1aWMDiIGh9yR44wKdJ2mlFkTumW6tFo/vZFVNUivZTOlSWCAOcY4lrAsYNYUlSyPez33SUbEdG6hUJa2nzXPCQqXf719unacWFkE/l7gN8HMp6enOeWitSpFwFTZNS@bCE1z0PqD73F97rIhaviRWG9WFvVgQq61LYXdk9EwdTyo1M@fXYxWAmnOoMUgIeP7Lius4k0rH6DuusQiYVQtBQJ6h6wFy4mWYXDODKZ5fT64QCTQ7vw4llxcvw1hBtoTLS8A7Rzag3dfAXKcdvQ21nGsdAO2C5rMdKGfGYLGXL4XY1rNPsvU6VPV5rqjl8rm8li0U8kUNBqpyrpAvQWfLFDJ5TQMouXKpXLyEdq0o72L07UW2fx609wp9fSKhV7j61EaLJd89Ma3zUlbi@Ugkq5eXsXdC7M6zTzQYWddeCRitP9Gkei2bL4MpiyYtCxlmgqZJWlbKqpKaxf8tBg3/Hx5eg7@GT4iV1YRj1Kn0BMZb4BFs9gh1s0wcduzg17kG7J7RXRNif6jTdut91/G8v0eYe7p9wr3um1yRcej1UMdPFHojczJcE@LFeITqmAz3HwzCwagDGURyyAPcg4drOc6qAEX24umaUj4OPx0AyODfDoDgzw4/engceR8f7O0/FArs3tGT@1deeT9Qnj06eHAcWovcN4iaD0H84sGjR1et/it39OJZf@q4eAsPjl7kFo/QCU/zCjm4lgOFzgTEf6CVOFJgRUCGyxcDgyrgGZC7IFff9Y35wsKYQeOn/Kiy6YVnEvip9YpwHJxf1hlS2o7BulzrFgr6pBHTFwLUYlkQxsx2zlgxw3qOZekuc/r9DXAc6ngW00BO2LKwJWLSZ45r9c7MnrEhPMZjn2UVv22PmRAeApDRtEsKHYALQv3KMKrZDNfEOtbUYNMxW@sIL3RCo2sOhjAGnzlBAKGj6wzuL3tBfCN6TW52mPA0yO2aj3U9uBATdmOlvCjui@JDfaLXq65RfFn1MpWKGo8/dcWyOIZhWfcGxsEMWi57AT1Jd@dpcSKLD5jcjg1wpcVyxijAeOMGcPxlrdHayV3US5l89q9/68d/9ye/PqjRvFEzs5@RtnceP3Im7B2yExUv58x1VqrYvVq@AnQPeGNG7K/PIsskLGnlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU0SJrFMogaGbWkFkr5spou5crAouTK4JsvF30GWwk4amWrAmDtLn6IfZvkLXkIghVfIGVvE3qSxfTQPmWiAXFEAYXbCR163zJrMLoyNcOyRQYQddZlsQcP9jMPHojiPbTgBpP9jCj20JIvZTLFe6JokM9@Cdkt0eFxSqjSUpxwSyZzD9A/5QDwaxCiOETLQQHn/UTRRMv@3oMHmE4fLRrGh2An3IdbrMBShGA2WoDvJwBvQmgQbI@nk6OMHqAFk0SfB9xnH/xE8aMgO@jzjAfjAB4GJd3bE8VDbtnbQ599KnaeZ/RraNmjSxRdsEC/EMUBGAYu9EhR7IARe4codsHUnevghh@9xw8G2BNdFOccPYggUZxRaL17IortwB2T@cTPTR6xWyGLyku9S5Yy/kRRCzKNwbKhJSuKudCSg7I9fPiJPpz0jAG/5i5/d6GkDx9mdXM2PXjQ@eijzmDQced7Bx89Q6/9/YfAqsynbmfQ8SN22nA5EGv/oaafjOZXLyj1Ybtd0a2VXl9rt3O6fcWrPW8bmEOI9QZy5l8DTGjU3gev/YftXX3VAjcBbCNhGMG7g9e9Ebzv6R3uFVzkRe9ZpyNWsfkrSjMhoDCBK9XYHU@A0Nrpkd51nSraZzWWSSM/M28UMq0qebARCAWZ6iX69xP41HFOKXk@b8xqmVZtVitqfIdUPyE2Z1reFNMbox21nK9s6DuqlkvNKqh3w@nHWVxSd1hCvbv1liWeJHc0EBDE5s6OJDbU1o6mliqF4sutqSgmK/jcyRYrbxOZeIYxfCQbxdZOMR@JUSymdEWrFIvApgFOJjDad3Cip51InBn6STKJuaVpBygClZXNqZxmtZ@YpWc1ni82T1ZnNbXKFWWzzDVgPfwqw7Q7cVwOcgDgZjuZCu6KSIhquSRCBhQlkUyGRE8B02L76qdfPz45Pv6M@MG6PyPy1DWQelV960cP9@XDo8CG31OQHyCb6rjyPlKtJR/OrwZOxyCgyA9hhAVhL3DD842uY8kHtO0PeN3AI1DpJPu6jeXjh0twng@dM54yqoeokoJMu2sw/NyE2WN6rQ4mvccSlCumJ89obG/X67V2bUQaFKCIQayvMfoWwwLMocfzHiqtoOjneObP92jXMpfVTm0WmwGcdo1J6quR03ulpbrVHn5l4l7tHkautuHdqRo1w3UdVwRRW6z2d@za1Pb0vvHUcFEdy@HRJnAaeBAw0WdGcpM1DzD0Pooxl1LdZfYiZ0@mo4Qu1TvJZSec7QsdEDmJrweFPqezqe2aKF5W@zWWeAlB34Dd3WSJnnwvuZOrAp7usXYSnDKv@q/6TGOFXJXEkATCgq5E@MFy6yxZq38NXhz2SaUCufEr@gSgYmIA2OyRB4Qem5fVbs1iCYnNWJKQlKsOag2MfoGPbUkUW5LUuGgJdUn6VKhDf63OY3rNm3boA0Us01G1TKE6Aze1mKsOoXr1l7OqWxtPXaNqgdWfJOTHcPUqIBVwB2DeXiTe/9I3kttSvsbdqgTqAieH2nK7NqvaqPIUGkYtWwOPVCOXSYOAD49iGsZ8rZBWC@lsOpeWiugKA346nwZHEICA70hYCZExMZ2ZZWQ1rRpqOpF5ZfZeJdMnCeBnCGksmZ44B/Z0xMAFqgrbJlnhDehJaVsWCGY9h@nbEjVWIBlVLBhgfcjGZnqIoJ4ZukUxkkmJZbcS1mYCw2weT8cHjValcjAbfx28EtKbnUKqmEm9TSariY1kzTPeCPWqUEfyQqUeb0DL9edPmTcdNaCWwaQWtUqj0cEiFjPpbCYLpTPbF4NtsS620pmNggpVdMmIbDBON6JTisjxLNzGbWTMLQOqTi1rVUGm@b1sSZPKSn4rn@FzjDymMPbJG2KSJZpicOQ8EY8XtXg8Ga/i@saG6E9nA00jehYH6hq/q@6IwIyJFbGsYYAFaaRTxZkgd8COXQrILLIcyL3nwuX55XZd@IrwHM@Kbmsv8Vd8@XjvCH9fAacyWEsvH784enH0QGAKbUIFzrO6UZWr7SpYJLm@K8QqjAElbfr6sJQNxr7s9tbUdv0lfzfxAATAFUiNeYO1aNuZYaJQxz5BXQs7LA5l0N1RQ9OyrYZWhLEPqGkQVNPUKmqYiuEBC7mu0Em6XDFLJ@mE2OwcMrudIvevsflcT0nBtMBdtjtIbfKTQWVxG@MV/Hh8MW4TI522T2MMN9G/rJ5WTzLlbYGQG7uy2766V9sbPNurMjFbLIrVvf02GMUEi1XFvA@0mnsYfxY/jh/Gt5N1sVQg1/IuTqOvnreoA3d1cqL6p5eKmbZYjbG2mPePCUaOOOXE7XJTwM358dh5nMXil/BbZPHl2@AEVAFgnGS2XwI9jIXZScaCJLS2@JJ51RNJzWxDk9mlY6AaPwbKYuFBUFwB95ePsrkCS5aDtZ2vxHdjcVxCqXjeu8UJQx@62hbrMQYCykk1ts3EUoCXt5mTqlgs@LaymPMLmPSTALETW3RwQO9rrzToTDHbCRxA1MRpQBjs83lcsYgpr8be51op@/jwyL7vPogcFXuJGYAc4Lm3auVle@NEhU6UFbMn6RjbjdFpCbEM6WvcARB@wtTqS0Q8E1/cP3os5hBZILSBUwIKxXMNiTY3LjYcXKJi4ebLd/bHX2dsHM/mcPNiLTar5fyN/2q9LqnbGqrlK7IKDJl9tSBlLuqcKNTJo6CBz/tf@kFutl0Cu5ZRwa5p@ZRWr6tbGkvGxu@/@H1UsHR@8MneIxbHhY2/@5MfacW/@5N/RdsJ45e02KFlizEIiUa1UIydn4/Pzy/h4n75WCt2bRdFCypTUcvl4pYMpVFKOhjaSoxXCDCJRTUZ86SYv2e0kJcSCVXRklvZUiYJPhe@ArWElimBNVjvIyexkBeTsYNnZl5Td7d3oGQ72ZxW3YCWpoYHjln42za8ckyIlR6/umAMLN16bzAwNTIpCqu8k9j2O2mbvcOltnfSBntVq@MuEBWPKQdLUVt4bBMXZOP1lLIVZyBcsnrjsnrZStFaFkjoLw1jy25ewUNzA0/uLDtt2fAztjz6YaTAwQNrYDO2XntiYiupKL2eeL1nbxssX4emsqUsDlOzrWCFiv8kqZl8/0u/oWmFv/uTX7toX7Q/00BAL5cLqhb72c@2p/bUM3r1nwGAG9TqBEI28dmo/wYNoXDOuApZ048VGuSuKMSmNgoiPHwgqqNwzoCJMwe20SNRXThFxpNqts01O/YSFGwLtW6kSZAhTWrJqiAEHD8XVNxBN00w2BbqPW60ksK58FX0Ar6GgbBTFb66AAUOI@BknG7bs6bumE4@JSie2kqzuxAFUvgqas3cIG0h/qAoqVWmbF2PyrPsEdaISWUjw/NQByeM58JXIYqvHN6as7GOim0wpGnDKCxjEMonefQakHYL0rZ4hDa5Jqj0PECa8dzxSDYIM8JXgS8jLJjArjFzGwJUgXJ9FRAAZUj4gM0W22bZJDs3U6nqQsHnJZ7AQIWleqBUQ8BoCK2HSlyCyFUMB04gROHniLFd@DUM3HLEMQDCYfDtFjUQwzA62ZADJq03HwwKYJGGuQQVjd29u8hVrWb2koxKhPBPzDHOMFI92KvzCsACEfZOryKmGapOrQauYbMDjKcou9DqJK4ztRqJykS0XgoC/D@40WKLvFJV5FHFAvj1xXtFF1AGkRHtvA67bLvGVK2YZGHmu5D3LmWKVBuEcnlzdkfWPgs8LyGHP4sFH/sConUcnbX12@1VrSoMpJYpfmkJdetxYuBrQ@Ha85D4HU6C2GEsKIppUei@6YLESPtAAsWdiayaxGgLRaeUDzojoeUYHlXIJ/FFsTA0g7eOCij9dDZIcVbXgQr1xo5NGitJoxaeE4EWATTKV/bHsz21z/DLfH7dUORojjxS9IctH3NMGjgdVE1EcXEbRsc19JMAN2lmDGTWHfWYVmYJamiklNAOwSUpEmW4A4IH4rhjGSPI0nPDoPOHXkVRBsCMTjukmfGxCe1q@MCEEcj2lPscwcqZeWIqx6giW3L6eEyR67mJIf@K3Y/v@PC1IFqOc8Is88Tgk/GJJS1BHgPRC6SHNGB2cQNiK7iZSMumcQZITfNQcBfhVeTGUjoSdyMxT15/Z9WNRBtr9ILGGxNqxTJOdTuCX7ouBH/OwZt7gZ4x0pYFdjkkuYavYagWR90hoeoswdeYViNlXTIu8owTYkwMNI2hURi7xinD2QMBxxggmt1AZw/2YijtV2kAoL4HPQsVkE7cCmqagpy4vUQXup5P4G12h2U1AQNyNXC@yjaAgVVfW4YOfhAVy@FNelAxMq1sIF2B3jnqgR/qOPGbH8YPWjeaSTnsonmzDR8cDjqUVo3xbhFY8hEL9g5sz1T0DfAsQA5X5GQjIaYAbEpMihx0GP9qdN7aBaIlFXYdUpohBB/VAIVYBR1JDmqYjHxCTwCPe7rHv7Piqyc9OzuTSWfu1DVlw8PPynmOrVvKeGAC0@0oE2M09j/gbXaVcQB3YZL41yTl8XC8M0O@tla@O@dvQeh7NX9DViLe9@I4OJ7iV9MGI9Kvh4rtPGpQD0z64mI34e8P4@1Pa6XPg/ZXwfYnleKXCATkNQAzS8/T3TQAS3e6J@n@Wa/qe5xShwTgUItG4IiarN3AMvICkznuhyGcCdLR0KtjndBSOUAS@VT5ImlewiDkPLD69rE5g0i2ccb2XFefJ8g/iaGxASfmxPawOQz75ANG1EF/ztUqm7PGvLUUfRZGh0Et3CjiovI84fxmoFzHNvrPuP8M/Gfcf7ZINEi2MWtxlgydLrE42OpR52oQEsHMgzCXXB/1wocgAz8OwhS5Ycj5ktsl3N0axQ7wzW1Qj7WgYUCbGAPCjYTSeNlsNFu2Z5xttVLKABq7SIiAGgfQjRbh9KwXmhH71qk1drwlJxtV7cKo5OcbnbpDvzXwtoJlDCuIGgbHl4naUQcjf0cLZwj8AgME5MPAE1mDvUnCTFZDpe7kCQ2nIS5wzDPW8DPTIu7L9/LdgF3iqOeIjQJqRQChe1gkyCb4sKDn8I@IBtThU9eBMEFYib57OEItffFWHDB5patwWlOlSorkSpKCbALakV2tXS1K4A9V0bjiFSnmpV//0exvfOns96FfrM49NVg@YFSFaFfB3afAQvjdhbDK6rVIvUIOlC3dMlwYuQ44f@qP1pDMlhKIGTwdLIJ3Zk66w0Sk8rtJXj90Tla0xUrYFOa1GhRxXuPdkveLAKUc4WE0z482DxqCH58TEICRWRnN8KPNotFmtRonHGy2JtpZJJMzyuSMR@GhZ2sy2fKjgfR0GAwvWD0t4E5xe6wI8FQ@jAIbNBaZp58auO/gNWoQxeUZP80FzaFW4LchZLGxnXVbK1NvRDIdIVpXAGBDvAagx79HXhGuEjxVCm0hjeKoDGgUt/nNgNMKaGBEgqtcy3YibGQkAwPDL6ZoHIC@K6YagqjSFDv@MvwW04FjcKvXHTPLIdVlx0z6yu8fxLGFmI100Aj3oWZySJBRknlh@@ppozxHjO1NQcABrq5z5rDECmYb3JWpH1XpWE5HGem4fwi/Usxd5fE8GcgPuEjFdsfORJ84uVyFC00mNbtV6XOZwRzYDn7cLKJpH3i9nmN4dnwCldp1BrbpGWmGSlBPDF/sMPwvhQhRPtk3Op4g@DvZuBiLoHm7Qla33TZtc9JuJ3CDaLISbpOn/aLYPONxAeVfMEXiA3nygR6NE07ntdGdJG@HiZ@N8KMdm92TxNHY90TlIHsMaFgX@H/wHQIHwzxnITmSSnpkpTuTBH0d5f/t7vvW28aRPa@tp0Bkp00mFCU5sZPIkTuyLSeaTuwc20km67jVtETZ7MiSWpT/qJPMd8652BfYvd9H2Fc573Cu9ilm61cFkKAky0737M5@m6/bIgmgUCgUCgWgUHXWP@@fktZ3EfvYZc5NgG@ksIFQMBgwLp4KsKStWMFDeJQ4LS9wddGfvruo@mnFCdyk/EoWQIYYnhpO0hiUHc6ornljdVLM1Hfw/fge2PgezMeXV@GTOMvSvCqJ31f1IyeFQBlTNB7djgaaTnKrPYVOBpXkM/QqKXBnFNtsn9cGpjXKWtPZ/Q7xh5e8xfSWIP7@JvrP70BTvH7X7gto2KuDMcmbc5i6OhyPMjZnzQ5lb7iQPdPVJay9fce6KC9CAe9AhSA1lgVXD960aWAOaNkdJxvIBvAtPA@TuCm@Zzu5qiTOwGl46anPKzd30XazHXaDcdh2dE7PgmtavE8LNpZXd2s4BB0Lvb6s9Ryau9wklaZxEF0yVW5gmcC7dN2b2UqyRAn38E45Y9i4mX5InxLN2OKrym41rQOWlxexHXsZYftzMB6MJWBDV4IRajkq84/0JHx93E4QooPMnmUvrdadJz73naRJd5gRkrx@tsnwp24gwsvWdB9@H4lubyl1rlWoano5lw1VNLvHo3k9bnGF4Uk5drobS97GdHfmOYvVBFgqwra@bwqZggwDmVbLsSHKl7k91u9NyQR843263g2zSnOGQE1KsqQbRbzcZv3CzWFl3KBfbDi9p18APA1HTWEo0zbsaen4vopTzoOBpbXoL6SkExSLikJyjYaVK2eeKfuXb0mdrRvrbE3V2crUmYyAbJVWplwrU6XuBXTPvC7ohp3RDdIZSVg70888sU3/ev1giN2KL8vRciXy1PLlcoUE8nK4XKk7JJSX28uVbX6IlysH/PB5ufITPaRja/nrcsUMC2QY0is/vMB3LcLx3lqubDnut9wo@BzGpl5/uZL0KeX5UV6ZIkQKtJu0Rhyx9fq6maNhSBMbK5WeAsfEHpZPvA/j8f8l@k@Cj3FYIiRij/MBZ1YPVTkzaVgzhtRD04YJezFjJFf0bF7f22EDsyQLqnlIazy7DIMnNXxxOSuMBDGk8okG/RKCkJuV2Rgpaya7Izq6duJQ7uRs/Uw9n/WBtsPpR5T5OK2EI87p8qa/siCkA@@GJwrfhOcUOqY6xghnsu4MtEDUX5bnNAp9ncVF977dQ7zXnc1E2BZMFuklBmvJdNLh@HAOlQ36gyyTcCpuOUR2Gd6Uk0EJ7p0oxlJBj8wbkvmzbhkEgz343XnNscoBtYwIQuJR6VhGWTIvsCxGUirrLE1VBh@hYMkcGuFh6zNH89vWj5xPxI3Hc8VN05ApK1Wy5MqKSSrsw3fZRTCS2pPFax0ezb5v@WpKXmOvxQEAq2RSi8jX/nfo733R341CbYgwUcEsxXr2VDqtXs@dZScw76bVTncgEj217c5UjpIaUpLT6sDSzOfx2pSKD5MPUfKl0gT6hLZvyJasCW6h2@TaQmBBSxheZj9@XqGPn1duJtS0RtK99I3S4qMmDUcanmCaNm0@rtLwWV2MFN7fDrrf3cHDbAfbnQd43IDhBMlllA8vemzlko5tEtvyBSK1XFEiyPm4NOnm9COJez66TY5t6cNec397b/f1R5p0nzx54uo5epzih1GLvdZkHhfIbK2ezAczli0rHkJu4bAb2/HxWX84uvepl5@SJSKsSRkIqBbDfnqMu1qWWfJ8YuxSOclrUVTD@pwOgyAjlaDqBJiyI03XEREkHDkPAg3EqLdEb49Xay4Hl2o2e8F52Gzy9GVik@tZDF1jTsTdvy/eK17EQ47BLZHRrnI5dgGitvfUh1e1Q3X4qq523m39pD7uvVMfaruH8P3w9t3m68aWov/ruwd1lcuY4iGKJBaURNftsBUiNrBaKZUeK4a81R@MRe44W658PwjO1at@K8Qx1fM4OH9xJi9@LxxtSKk6LUfH2MOMOGroeTSCvQWHuaRlLJSbNt/MxPUKRXlPaE17jjXveb8ddSLKm8PadxCFsbnMp7oR9SDJW3Of3RMlCREt2XSII9XCAuuKigeUH2c3BCYQ@yuQGDkkBGbbV5pwyb/vpuBhff/NgYIbka293e3GYWNv90Dt7O3T69uPjd2XRM/GweF@Y/Mdkjjjm73txk5jq8YfBIGSr@Df49eLeDQXBR/ZmSqtzzj59gfU/clbdtcbGry6CviOaqyWL3qQPlHQjX4P28vruYsY6gvuxfJRgXKWavsv39Ocr8LfcMJpjoLZ/iD/LuYoq0sl9Zxro8GyQeNtXQ9XmvYKZZfPI87HCoGWwnX2@@Hws6cMcDbiaUehym/BRgV73@IehMeyAU0V3SPYAGUMVqqKA6QtL3vPGeQG1dbq9uEPVmoTI0L9gqIvjKnJeo4ppm1lABQXSBo97AeV15MPxPf0YUVXOxpKBvUo@SAZ1GP5AFW0AdsRtapzXIz2LiCe1Zp8@PV8sMPHwupJ8mEz4FXsU42T9Bt3aaCSAJNwltLlMHiyy8OheoO4FUVcJOb8CBHX7crACCU4KclEOUpk2zbKmSdh08FRgzZ7k6DfSCVugJ1Q0BnFyqm6vjqEcVDYiyQA4Wk36IkJVGq6w7ynnsIzVVVfgY@SwH18JWfQZwZE0NAsHkm5ba0VhnctRyU3p2oMtI0kB881Jmi3IbA5hcAfAUOACpmVTotnKr42DDD9jmZlJ@4TR2Lf9m92fmLn9kUrzBTQVlvOr9Hvv7uayF5mnWTsFBk76qLfwyGplXyU2ekPaYyzWOVQZ5CCrbP@YBRJHzrZFvCJE09zlBsTG9X2S3UjUxvoMFljr9@zKj0hLr6h1hNiyrvUyhwvZ@eJ@EpjYBPn0yQsdndAJzjpX4bW2ZmHQ6SrENsvpAjzWTk2P8cjxkT0z1wqO/6mEDr3aXVje/NT4W@/eIifK2JBwlcbo0P8T4yJumh48DkfGywOoXfpkWbiHsYXJyitbfC0tMQoN8BoHXgW0bruRXM9SRNz4@nvuK40@Z0/fv1alVIFSCYd8zw@c1Lp5qkjU6XHZY6VNgGxZCchS7LeMV88hpnI6xe4ooRegKOlHuQI1u0TUQW1CDGtO7nokGTRwZ11dyfwXbXBFhVGkRTfGHZ/FH92NqsPN9xialCiLHI6RkR7BnLZdS2zFJ6vpsBtzwdH8vvu4J7OxU6mh@@Ctj0X2nfhVnh4MyyZlixYdwf7tzlgZXL7Q2Cp7d7NgGWSnIaWcHrCnN7SYmJNO7/GX6b6jscegcHcix2UBKhV20WPj6iNd3VHCrg2mFQhOjjcru/vq7ysT6gsyT0sGdpaDAL2PfU2tbaNeizs/ERpShbLifJkvmQs2sy/eYN5JvFuEBVaB/E0PRJhkfpw70TXIvX0zMIqBFvfs0A0lMti98XIoPhIA/5Ga0BCNu00q4G5mc1clMknim0jcE03T3Rj24afLaxl7kbI5OHYBmTbBAWnuFkyu/8@iH5cMfWIggUnU2hwmzRpmm9onXBAFQ8oo@9ne3BOt5guhZG9KNiLhnYw/CplNew/z1DMSKKEiy5siXWtHGvURD9eMmoOGyRiGghg6akTxaKZEoyI5y/P7Q5100nPyU5BpGQiiO4Lmyuo@PE3PYUxNZJ5spoo5PZYW2JsjgyWx9id1bDXb850H7bQa5PiYbIqkrZzqyr8Y6qSWSJTk6H5zMaYRIK8trr66DbYk60wxQt/FrbMIZPyc3Q@oPV9CjIex7y9T5zb2PVMesoAc0gnpvVmwEwUJFVnxpySaTtPRjZ@hIvsCxEyiFCAuMSTtbrqegK32dBlRrKhc5apNlhDOGmojJop6n@bXx0E8q313fv@@mSwIRNMB7/BKv9NfxiH6a08y2eO9Qm@BrLfwuGwx9nkPtM5oDh8jWnuZTu@bScGr9IqJPJ5m92Sjr6dJGa3ntlr4Ep4e9FHKHLs7q1Pbu8Vyut2U3car@vqAbsX7WT2IvPDvGvJnntRbx4CLIN5XwLTB9/hux9X6H/CwTMgiUx8m89h2ri34sYUIa35iGNWabNQLVvLk73fiVtBD15WvPz9WOW9H6gg78LW93bcWTvrpfVMeUIuHvQcKuXlC36ei9I3bOgCUhaE9Ca@WxMWbmoYS0lcrzntwz4KB1vhteyeseVkUCw/La09y3Hret7IOz96duw9aFXziibfoHceXwyv2p9P@2eXHdVVg19Prlvj339TavWxekR1rfwgXp7La9Uiu9V9Qn@fqmcl5lyN4I98SR6hsX2JGazUskrX4ev3lMsPvGiu4IbEBJeqB@eGC3HFblQ9P1o7rvaqpfXzo97xOi75jR5WRw/LDx18@IFmUZIxcjJ/NDrGnGrvuoa9SwVPqhybVl8NUXw1hL68CYZR/3Vt92VmNw4KALbAtK03b6hLGPIFWLPh7onfC68cvU3mKXBsDgpSboFvBZXhDID3k7Ed044IM@oVj7TZ@Jr/jt3cQsm/GIz6nGLcX4K11Nfoa27BXGMq8Y4CZTmKjJNM3C8gOGkeBwdD8nUsVtSFsqhrZdyddC0QRyjJ4jD/KZ/HnUIgqu9yHR3nYj8MWmdAoktq9Vcupp4/V3gjVot93sWDKUcw5AsTpWM84gCEfgZ82oAqWHOP@dpHjpqP9zIe5AvvUY34ngwbyOdYU0QKzL/VF77fxOWfEwGE8Auic/l6i1NrXqRIyt1B3lyAb7nswh/HDLhWKZ2ygMYCttRXTYGzpTjTCNVqMtH3hSuQU2hF/3QLCmV@m2pGkt@V7EwSPqfWbzFoyV3KSRv46abFHKtYwRQzmS1SLNxKDex00fLoTUjDaqy2wm6XkBZaLKTkwCPf79X1P0zqj49Q53GCvKQXptILmXRf0gWpNJdPE3yaqWJnyi9@SfN9U/k0mzdVV1Wx8uJTT7d8UknSvOvz8sb@qN@M0swbSVcKVyYJzzMJBSvl5xm9Lyn3MmUSBk/SjyRd8/eK7vkEy0zeF9n68ZvTHRSy8ay2NZngUr8XdX/M6ZDtOgVslidqKiXFORinMoOqqu9ganFCGhz2@XnYblRTKA/LRuLwmMlvPH@R97WS8aMziYbcYpwaWDPGiEUlrvMhE@6aLyxSPZx8zwLBMMFoyozcDVN4rAuPLbDIdc9UK7cgpwY4NW1yiFdxL/Ir/pjBnkXO5FucnbggmF9L4@V2c5ZALHTv5WeTKStNcF1EPupGzZlF0rrHkxBnC4ldaxc4qTOUO9gdbIPfS@SELSiMpJiie5KiKZ1mKBv2vakLkfgt9/fig9zLgHTsQTe8VjUsMwK@hZXLXHAfhfEohp8tdgEUXwwGXZw6ssJ3xVeodeCClVUct6QQrZndzzVg2SP5PTzpC@lUyFd7gHwFA5E0Ib44PcVlMtyA7V9BtGLHJRr5uVpvLBsaNGYercg181DB@QYL4G50aiMhPSejB5SOB0Er9HOko8Wk/eSkqZ1Ix7Dl/XTcG4E7N5rSKrncv1xErc9bL3Ge@6RcelS2SHapj4NL/qPH6QUrIpJJWIFHxtXy41zOOhtuydlwAQA99RoT/XvizfAy7PXCXI1mDM4Yk9Iah8PLsO3ncvthcggMuGBlnEziHnb/YtiSzR1SugJiRtwSjj05DiMOwy/mZzkubvFZmZfDoVV62kxdfRm1QUBz46TTx@kwH1jATYDQA4XOwxER5YGrsijx2bPGhXWXc2xEETXg58Q6m0jI0OuPohb1DO9k5boESo5B0sp67QlMqL5WN8DlYH8WArgek1LAIGCOkubhkNOH5t@Fg9INM2fsgemZIkm/Po8VGu7hMCLpmxKYe4WLWbhTBx@@ahyog72dww@1/bqi57f7e@8b2/VttfmRz7hxUM6Oj9WrvdckXZLTdDk136MP@doBlcxzQq62@1HV//p2v35woPb2VePN29cNgkbg92u7h436gacau1uv323z6TtBULt7h@p1403jkLId7nlcqymWS8upvR31pr6/9Ypea5uN143Dj1zjTuNwF5XhVL@m3tb2Dxtb717X9tXbd/tv9w7qCg3LbTcOtl7XGm/q2z7VT3Wq@vv67qE6eFV7/XqioXsfduv7io0ErFZu1gnL2iYtYVETt3O7sV/fOkSD0qctIh4h@NpTB2/rWw081P9ap@bU9j96GuhB/V/eUSZKVNu1N7WX1LiccwtVqF@23u3X4T4JlDh4t3lw2Dh8d1hXL/f2tpnWB/X9942t@sG6yr3eO2CCvTuoewrhM7lqgkHUonR63nx30GC6NXYPac549xb2Di518gciDGFZo6LbTGCYQaC1RKS9/Y@ACjpwB3jqw6s6fd8HTZlaNVABFhVbh3Y2qpCIeGg3U@3WX75uvKzvbtWRvAcwHxoHdZc6rHGADA0YZHwk1qFK33Gr0U@ElzwSs@YM53rcnaqxo2rb7xvAXOcmDjhoaG5hsm290jT34fvY2kSJ@tgzCM7tjZXO9KfLEN4@p3dkZu/RJB6Ttva26zQja2dX@TThHc06TydcKdlpNNMkifSacVnTDk8uTptRr9PHHdOkmGx8nMenHkI6uYiG8yk3J1Sa3l/hAouLzeb7WpMWugfNpuvdpWQGjdtK6G3weblc3UYEvcDKGxs/lYrQ/XmGUBs/6INONtTDAQRyCvV/ENO34Dx0VbHYDnUxXN4HYLN1FMuxyRmOUkg08mVHhPFJq@SdCX6PNDtwQceA91tN7JPCMpIz9WP60/uavsjkYH0g6SzbXcUiFrGMRvR7aKqRStglAv/RHgmiDlfpx2H4@dQp2dVhze@f9vttx3VNGc47onXgqePeUvwkPJ0oXpgsz8jysbOOFxGbdTerMMn5syaZ0v3iD7llDv40R/zjGmzE5wN2Tbkq3qzWm5bOD1IcFkme0q4tcL2COxk635vaXxsfsJorrTxen/j@KvkuYwv2gvALTBPeEZc75p9Xx5KBBhj74iCSRNpDRrFolTH2JknmK8p4hkxXURuWPzRXn4U8rxNJSJG9CLp2nZiNh9G1jT3J4Zf7tTeb73Z2SHQC28dPV5@srecSt1t/9eT3I@ph173sdWxA8zjpaZxkjZItUnx4pFie01P2ZwYuFpERDvNNp/FH@HlI7DaylkwQZGhujJhWPZjo5UPQIa/YAce9nOHXmSNTM4CTaaqL1pwH16ziB6QrMQ9oY5bumHvtGn8AOxn@ZognDdIMpFmMnRkT59LqguVefseYivLihh33IIufN3wsbtwSGvBWF9vP4nYtv2netnoxFlNGjFfudi5JSNybxEIZu4qejOy37GdEbwCz9zD68lfNb/T4UTu4Y3d3QTyqjQ6IjDtJSexTp5vRutFHGvIxApjAqZqp6bnCLr@rkeKxp7eTE8cg1mhgVBCNBza@WcDriR@RySrZAvbFsqu@CKfCeQfgrGuO1e/EubOao6GsG/8h@t14pVACK3FyIlS7SurImSwfEz8WhpwZMv0pejD8fyJNZsB/TitOgp5Sy3ICeCdKMlShFS1fmSjRlTlosE43Umranz6mYL7ZHXOWNEyf3lzL/Roige6dsfnwkd0edpwZBACTY2PDHr@JSdpZQEunF3lXF8c5Sa91PnCUnivMVDEFt7B27LHa5ZmzFby4ypW9JqvC11RUvZCF2wmPeloyTSzl1f04L@Bc4/@j@IA3QJIBz1x6Jlark5xV0qPMyAHtasmacNqJxyRSS7/deGr3QFkuMjOyX598GUIR6A3gM91OjuTSV2Kem/W4yDOxOmQveHDQjmUyJh/tsu6EDTG7IeDcb/NmCIK9jK4wQXQFOrvqS6Ep5z4biqCS1Oow9TMIcev6RFqeVq8S7HlnEhyaYP@uJ7EBQtnVMjl8cfChMbSvy/vqTTAmlLt3a7awWPHBQd@D7SIqk20JXR6BbVr9/pBUxwDtJhy9aOz66oPedAh78cVQ@y@k@Swa6h0Jo/RTNVCbZPXO04w45WfU4miE2wptn/mDm3QewkJU3JNcF9aUQ8xreHTDbDpG1w/LynmepjwnmrBbUibic7Wmvn6VXEJQ7TI0ZApGcbK4YJtNrgfnDsnwu@oPP2PuhwrUa4ftxDOpBZL3AqWTGj328dgaSdMH/Zh3NKgrsAOSUKIsG2mJoSrN0U80O2m7pnzqHRO@S7kl319PwqTGWooqShlX107Mt1agzgSVVrRr0MRZaHlllVGZteD6duNijL2FZo@tVf5TLxEpFVEiqveN6ognkZvJ00c86U3@6v0Yo4e@4Ixbq6BAGDorzlWn5RzjB5uCD1E4bNt7oqTJtIMBtt946dPvMS@arUPt9q8VjOJwTCuAVjG6LjKMpvOX/lmvudXvBqdRPwponQaP@tci8fA45kd02OmwfxVzzCYJRGllao/TZ/EvI27Y8J6cS65brrniUThwbDOF0XBcOxM3EbxzDiPANNAs8/dg0kdaUubxalool71/yvZ4ZXf9xrKPyrMKy4k@AGgBtzFhQSF3SEd8Mcm6fLo@leFkXgYLxxNVUIF7g8VeBuNnRCI@hslgbJCZMkuwG4GV2Y0YH7WvvTb7IBzC0VK4HSLEUOzwZy9A9G6SIj/CUqCiyk9LVlE5RbmGH0I8jG8m98qTfzL2hMCfQL/8aBa3zGIEFnEd420plvWK9jJKuLB5YMQymiUxSbHoNOpZ1w85nsf1JNRs8vgmarDlDylF2s3eFFdiRDq08EFoQadJIqc5djGpLKtll/12QAWpjZzSzQwb3mY/y4Mfh7iycwbBtKUhOxbSN5GqRVRCdOQJ81obZfGpfPuIWVm5a69NELA6y@TMitPt5I3mwjdQIplfcazVH5Iwzk9QT5t6LMej/mD5jtS7UXbM9Mw2i9Yt173VEFiYrUqT5YM2k7Y6xuN4PTeJzwTTZCnGlmbEQ1i@8nPC5pNEvK42Md6qzfEtdLiJZqndVDKpJP3dlrGPSfESFr1mokmGFOMOJ6XryfejJjW8ebME0TBledVkidGEyGiO5dECNUGmhEp3pxBzn8Z9gh5tohzqbRPt7P65kaiTRnLG5alJyji5BD3huB2XNkkuDTowvoCbONFwEyGVKJzX3piP8sqFEzgZRoIAhFYcFtJ9KNnBTTtrgo84OkDHacJaqAxJRE8btoVD4vQ/IRh75debO9rioTkulI/XBdJ1AolWFZxrHiRz35xej5rXDGWKFDTEZ5AiadGUbDq7e6v@bFsoH0GQ0pysLX1LHhrjqoeEDf2xk5rX0IHTqnTJzIjKDoQmiwYaC7RKOe2GslyF9hcNheNh3aCHES0g5LODn4e6BNx5r5USaqPIdXuMLK4mt4w2VxU2pEjKUPIO8uuhKKouL1wJQCgYU/lqmSDArSljj0MBdr1jc14GUd1HVLBaxrCkj@wVNbXznJEOouoMj1etHKVZOZ7ZMAozgZBiMTtPigjpLLOzpFBoopuJi5Xjyez2pDlIITa8LxSnrtC9kqVh0nNCQI7uXXJTiXJUVl5JczAnPl51M4kJf3Pqs5KVWppMJfokGB4VypOpT0uZ1Ey1KyvZopmSRA/XrjWTSKRwbYQTqfDn/vHVFNvleWITai0yMlqGts9G9HVaZdK6zf81Vs/5UrbRMQw8@2a4WX41JcRKxin7fAfsapmPDOC7/U@31limGkx0rAD2S2cuuziyIGSNNY@pHs3CStd42kscFJg1bb@j3h/u7GTcvp6MjaHReThcLZVKYOIT2/m9sa3GVlLUL2ZzFzsX3W5xcPWX4fuTIsv@MOSQABWzgg6pS2hQxH5/eCqRIYADZUXugr7IirX@Radjh2DACSU6j7pNcmpvCIonoCgxenl/yBtADFJPsL@ggWjfLyoZfVeBKJoaijmGotIwCb7Mm9MzIg8@dGCfnZxUMTAIZmPNRPOWW934ghkEkU24s9h9sfslNU/Ovwq73b6nPiDqMzwFLHybLLCzYxcoSRacMPLt3ouY/dF6KryMuta9YmSxeR3gzMRk4kwYv/Dwjb8fntavB07@6Oc8TSvU5Ido5kP4p/ZU/jTvamfxdwArfEho3yn3eTBwWkynycw01esRnD4RRo/K3sy1TyaLy3timma35wZRZ6Prs7MGarrLuoDxZc/dyy25IXtC3Pyn63IHNCwJDI0TfK7crQSumv3zxOLlqNO5m1TkMADSsd8lESUSyp8TiHwGwCNQDz@iJ7xo/1SgYb0z4VBEFBwE65iWOyjQRIFc7n6r@tuVU6vV1NLg4UNVq23SQ6Ggaps1tY0Pm5tqm9438f5DdWV1dV1k7rb7hT5umo/f1CbB4B3Oh62z4Ta9UloV98ZgrY0uXipWl7z1pWb1@cZ6XDyqbeJaPz3957/91//89/9WrOmX/4GXTX45@jnJ5Pt@can1ZemHb@t4P9o@Xl46OVoaHC@froPL/s5ew/uNUSFIzUf94UluUWYB6yvbkZp1Nnuf0UWVCRt4Hgw/k3SpqMVWXFzUX2OJHMUydrEVWt9D3KM8oSW8CTowuZQnJBYJ6Bjb8dQ7rRAGeDTfECUJF9iBSnk5WzEb93AHk2RITlUWtSce1lkvQ9xpST0p4C4uzViFqBeHPeyAX7LOK83L5QL6jUZNzb/Fn9/Ep5v9a/Xgk6MelNQDTz3I5/mnvPaMvrpLxQi3cyUbLQfyeY9S0qMFmBmqOGJFj9cPHGtngty53BKH7AEk46aCM8stOC9Z/fFlGQm4Fp/mFhDVVMkWCR8yocjil6XeN@qWL5TjWz5z1YYVhaZexXBl1olK0r9QgYJYDAHSms@FIJU@VYmTPr6RjKei@aL7OsfRhBgwyLr/cofHPT7QXLTU0zbPmbUUwhyx@bx8xdy4LpehGW2kSP0pAnygIsvJEt8kXF5czomVt9VKbqbcwrbbp5lPbB3G4cjYpkuhvymLCcSa2ybcUk/fa9GG3HK8ovJRcrxiVZWftP1WOavI@UV3FA30dQWuHQPqS1LbNxlJ6FEGJHDEZ39leoTxRoHxFDXRLRIsa6zafTRdRkJPX02nDnZ9OTmyiFD82aGx/XVibLtFviVi2EF4gJFKTPk6QdSNtdeVIRP7NBieIDpg0OGAaiM5N@P9PESnncC430mQ9hkym5yn45masjgYBqfngacWd/uHw2DcoGmLNJ9Ry3ephXDBBCQw@HTVs5pnEJYW6S5hiiRNYcshBC/ojnV4NOnbfHLnBF1qhoJ2u4JBkGEnpmT4NdNXE3RMufo7OsFGeUp4J6eRWsSy5IWlkYaUt6/N8DCbGjo5U4M9dpKBk88JqsnINLygC11goj3ng1@S5F34CNB15/UtQH0VYe0Z6sfsdBr2gszkNOjmzEX/4rqSeRHjmUNRijVSTkN5Uk4j3gEr0iN/znqBkLnJuDPKLTjOwqdYh3NbtOcRdvKd2OIXAxUlAeg4gBnfDFHvepEIy4kZKo2B4asGW/4ThE43OCX8xlfBGKz4adH58V7RPfr5U@/4gfOp9/XT7y5jokWymWULalEfZhuJpccKzYxFL/NqrNJi42rwUy@b4VNPyR0WiwSESNE5@rl4/LVICH1adN0HxU@LQpBMlwGT4vz6igBfnEJzMYtFcTG34D5wTec7P5ZdRXMr/6IP5YMrv4SFWVTyNj2tc4YdAsX3dH@7kCsncfHpSunxSvkxrYROw@vCMLzAfFuIL07Ca1IlYixnaer59HuGGzKE@HYdB@v08ZraKWFN5O5JrC8paRGqhznXk0vYisr4whOUn6jM7lJxxcVN8gQ4fMSC31PEciYv@4IS00GL@xzMn3H/HPUEMeTa5O0Q4UhYGYiNCG@hFgDZBF@5iUNdM1yW@Z6Tr7bgu5WBUPcWF63ZotfvFbSy5vrL61CicWum@7T0tDQ5RqeGaGaELmllavmeKm/8@OQ//vveb4ujxY2V4och/Y4Wf1tce7ooj/RAb4/M2@XixuJzZFv7tjgu0hqYHp/8x/@k8ht/IThIGT@nPxurBtbaeHGjUOUiXxc31uihvLJC9f6vf/1XasOSrNgQi3Wp6SlGbN1QZCvoMe9SumqglbIsXU7FCl/MAgyxMKS1Ob3AMOp65WmJt@kWtVXFZag9Xxl7FD3Fs2HWiE2FZCfD2FOQZiQFqqigICCNCUVHWbYbxmwDzJuiqX6576/FtAL4RZtzJFUmphv3Y5gMLcmyiDrQkRppPS8PG6Uf84l5RyVvbErWjQqJpZ2WtU8frRM7vO2Ho6iVtZIww/W8FVyFJz740A/bF7Sm6sXd/q/D4iWx5Hl55Wmxg839IttxFwcMqTAY@7@TIqiDAdHCkI1OPTWkHuifw4WXx9GCSKHfSc6kTDxJ0rIHYUv2sLIxiSmL3PHz5HgYzfFTVdrhv6TAI3KmDgRpxUr71KOSe/sVlX@YZJR8vOZ1gc1bNo7VLjAKYg07YNnk57gN2B007fFrw1O@hMSl4HVdsvhBu90MdJqTW8ibUGlebuEs7A6q@Y64d4fvVJyYaPqLmnkjlEKEHYRCgQUdYJ2Ho4CW6NU8f8F6PK0BblL0WWviKi4la0fn1av6dpWjrsyp@kqqvqIehZaQ1pPwjOWNTdnZRLZUsVU5DJs4UptZMdUWm6DNQ59/gEEs3dLo4FqCbg7fgCSqpc3RVmV2t3m8FiYeuQrlzp5sLUrk6txievnRMznkBjV0J9TrS2UkIOAFtwILZXo/kBsQVRNmNOrlxJ/fRLLx76HBcBv24ErUdlsnzkdlWupdIvZNNOK7lIpIoP3K2jbYOZk9EtCJi60kBG0eGy95FyzVqfBiizOa7qhwGGjjEiqfl32qo5ZKwst2dPRaCRRBH/Kl8sqjx6trT54@Q5SzBd3a2WBQyMcqYHAWEAzWqB1aZON7tZpfzssnhKCerhLQZ4HFARzMuq5c17h9vnLvVcslDayUZ1hXHEZDiuvtSgaZQhyGPmYEWqM4w7zj/Fg5QsOOP7Xdr/Q/8bfxD8gMZ9zRBkJ6qx/epp6pcuficKDKgpmd4jiP4EHF1Sl23rDf2Ye3iRC2rsL2VNFreIAYnQ37F6dnNnf42rXVIQ0YIjj7pcYK6mU4Sh2MWVhBF9UbDg3r9kXVwDuabgGMcjElQOcT4DTMtN/KQFuaYnQs0yQEz5q4sYojRMt01GZn5s5eX9V3tycRW7TD0DFc37ZsJeWOPZnBgQxi9VrNPSTqam8XfJVUyyQv41WZBVwJ@cp8HT7AXekWAlFbVDGymvWGkTOPLGXmxdS1aVqU@hF4zYBZLt1OSnOv1bQCBDGCUO8mJULMS85zbJKlONmdjHEKXs5XLBvRN1Ecs4M5XVne1RalnImjCizkbgCIfZtSXhpSqqBH@bHOgZeltxHMUW5FY2tAmyEnK9VwZk4OM8FWt7E4wEbUcUMLtL@xu@Wp7Tr92fmw7UFR3qz9hHYnIZ5vxres8S1XVGPHdIHtLZZtbmEz9RuuKBGzlLTD2BRBCN@OREUMU68B9caOpr0M6qPM2D5OuQLsGmgl3OyO6kECRy@8B7KgF@@JKw6@rsPfKrJ5NS1pEpcqeljIFtf8gW3RZCGtNYEkpLwDiJVJEImjlpTbF1KGFwt01rwDvXYxjN3Ymc3TGZaVBRWp7TtFInuWZ2@kzDy2WNFssVJBP87jC@bbubxxEnb6@i5awhy38Ma9P8YbhbszR@H/C@ao/3O445HmjkcVyB7hjsRtON/o5DDs/RkcczLmObjZjk4j7A91rFc0ouRZAFjgAUPcIaXEcgltu0GcKGd2wsPJ@QhGQiuruBjwhxr/WDf@cQUylx@3w/9XG1/4Bzd@VTd@tYK5ZkbPa9XOcrf@j2lxqhI62Q8zuxfqrmRz/2hL13RL1yqYTWd08//1lhb@D7X0iW7pkwo8JsiBg7ivn8/NoonUDrYajdTcws9pp10O4tjP5koXa692NU@Lh073Ij6rQltXfxj/pxr/p5BG/IQwdDiLSGxDk7W8LE/lsrxolrzLoXDJSloi7TWe0a326gkrXY/oCUqENG9sDfVChRRyTxLT0yY/1R9T6ZtMPnfFWWS7DpaJg3NrAS0rwrKbDnHRfHWQzJW1ZF7ZZh/Iautw//XD/yJkOA8@61tohDy69irsds1MYi/BDhOvU7oxVnMA@0CvOTKsosnJyI70be@EXRZulmrs2GJiXpy9SJCjNpz/0VrqHPqGFZUbW0ZEG1@XN6sqmOaa5YV8obZLptlN1i3@Q1z6THPps4ra1wuDm0gV6A0/zYvpOm1ldXXeHCClfPxgAJY8yj9nVP1v)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/5fjxd)

fish-jit is separated from ><>/Gol><> by comparing `.1 * 3 - .3` to `0` (it is `0` only in fish-jit)
(this is a shorter and DOBELA-friendlier variant of `.1 + .2 - .3`).

Code:

```
;:n@04+7*aa\ 
 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn;
```

Answer (score 1):

## 385. [*><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/starfish) ([Funge++](https://github.com/cwesson/funge-plus-plus)), 16574 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\;:n@04+7*aa\ 
_+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn;
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata>;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?4|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0-<?MLot ~<p>3:s4oya 8:nd=5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6yfX@uC/SmXogA5kh8QwjSq/NyZJj0GbQjZ/rBrIQ/SaAl/a1OnE9CPz0uScHH25IJGyInVz@Slb0KD1qzk5soubYTTo2D2EvLtiGf1QdPMTg8Lt/OB8VTJr21MDT9fzbOZPaJiRTq6n5MtvBz1JVmJqhNPFLe2Wuxy9IrME2z/2D55WKesk2akysiMw/@h@q5eaqpQEwKsWFQjHpRGWbE/DZDI6tM/pKCrtgNNsG4r2az4BNVqIKPKr@wX7I0@b508OnB8@P945fPG9kWpf@wf@gFLYNqQXqRe5keyIU3scbcPFc0TwpnLAgOfqCC87SeUG5GH4VarlotaWiLQol7mCczXPbVhTSfaBIl5A/SeSpkS@OReDEYQclpgry1V5UuBoC0qYAdcRBi5QmVFqFZVYlPNaBI920ff@rH1EjX/zIXgU/s4cJ@7rBoS0PHKfnp@gZ7PYrSPHB3uGjF88OWJDBRas5M3uTYa2c56rjuT4WqKe@SZtBayzuR4lDXdVq8QdxQExcjrMKaasgte3Q0CFYgB3Uc@HH3mKJTYIPGIyHlaL8528ol3EZzzUkIWw8yFQckoU2Tw1lY2ODHUMjYfefHX5y8Ixh/g/ukzOiCEGwYzwq/2c/7vEPnwSqrIIPDLojYh9JFZAQVZcR6JBYqLlAnFPfHa//zCB9aISUSYRfOAk/0SQI9AEcaLdnpIXyiobCJCkN459F9BVIBglREwo@loBLaKgM0vXYqemZqMoC89BH3YzLjR133ZE@Upnt4TcU8UuNOn2FB7I@tSdc/5mvBSkGLU0OaU6abVJm@Td7xEjA@PYGNPaOAZIF82wT@NRJhb2GlojLVBWu6kSS6vFrUQLQFTJJyI1GAl5T5ugpTVd5/2v/RBlUGZgnYP6Ob55l7oHtV3xbH8y/ys0vFWxo15U/LvISzRAqbPVLwDMS4h9xH/l0pM3VyywQhzoqA8LKzBFU0ylhHYPzFPhTAnq8gJNofAKVBs0NasxXK8PTM9xWAjXGVhQFmxRKuzId6jFmfIftFc2xhXwhpyqQSek0AEifehig6gAOMJmsQDcRTs1x7RVIUNvb20zEKS@jVqjymlU27ZdZ8VWY0U0IK5wNMXMNBnEgyiIG@NX9aDD6pNQkRkXqFVfjSLh6DgxL5I/DF9ptHxEiSwCyOI4M/HbADL8yOgFG0NeA3MHvckY@A7TpA5JUGJPIlBQFXyHLE2cCzQc66eJDX1whC@4w50Mgqhb1@Ld3SfEwtkf5es9a6BEIvjfk9zUZaQAHlc1cHU2jdSt@iiCeI4iKuKr5Nl6y5qRptxTeNhk00x@uaMw2mH9ZGaxps7zce9fVziauKo1FZLHd57aDc3sPoDAsoSlaVlELyUWRcrmVRfJL5CcDxUHdVheQHJApIBldw3ztjL29/YPDj4@ePr@mWpVCxq8GA7pf3041JTndaIWGeLRYy1Vy74Hy/PG9B0FFLDJdiFBjIPx@SdSbSrKYskeQiyNgV4u2KodXS7c@x59yJRFX85vVbsoaRbqWDzXzJdKlYxjSAzpMeTVxrbQKW/n8TVlawFMioPf5SfhrWU0kzy8bLWCs7Vj8ektY0RFexuQt7ARganpbmwo29uuFw4KFX8U@xu8NetG@mF3dF8XNLGruQ0UcE@dkodvQd4h4RMobJAMkUpCVIOja3nfEmfSFBk6Nf7Wbq/yLKjSLZLiQuQnjEVDHwQfAkYos9Af7qnOHuje0zI4QKJLjKnQDTZ@h9lyuBC6RFPyv0PCEE/4nwWeVmUx7LhNJpHYEK81u0sYbwEsK0KGRu3s69YbsqTPmXyWgvTX3jcD0zAHye3/K5@IM9vF0BOH69Hpm0DonUG4JIgMm42FWOS8FVMJXxjtLobpjSK@BKnn9gsujXj4xS8pDY9YzB0DbE8k0ULQ7qtpiocJeLDQp6LXjItXZohZu7IofoX6DKNq/lNbm2SIDekOXTbtnzBLxs3iy0oL00T1@9ulpPCmuakukPdpXp9y7qkY6zH5RvZmS6BO/dwY6mldRi3L5OpUAt6uAuTrD4JNo5bI89AT6xGUNOffnE/cRGIGNSPRH@pglpjZXBSkzsiaaCTtNOvKkOlcza7NUigQqeJGHzChmn0x8/E7o9pwllBp@BRVcPbuHr7fmmDVUWW6BmRJJsk38VOE@cFyoHDUpgBAMUSoEtoZNCMQMyBHvJDJv4BAH/SEsvEih5gpv@nIbLQc5iBMqNavfZZFPTy5zjmK5XPErdJkqlhm0vuvkUFYA7DU6F/D1gF1fSxTgDMRfWYgtCPl1ihejdGM8Iw999VKQnVhENXSgdYoBrIXi5u7QxTtxYENfAf6gUnlx/KBdSioiC9VUDVyzh8uV/OsGoYjnf48KuqmyFDRe5RLdRxgNFYK2uR4s1Ev5gDqMeIWkxqJo8JUqB8Kyt2ibqnpjq/cj@rUAIXM4APjHedsBOFTiGsxjrvBbTex/9rMYMhuJTVU9abunqXg@U4WHWs2zPLuz2ZSkzUamtrupgxQ1eTNrgkyubOXunxrDfu9woDRFkWVZTlG2zs/P4w@2npov86wg9Uyt8GY2v8wWsm9ml1m19OZkrBYa8ptZSyzV0ict9vTpZ@/a75Li7HT@RmwmtNj@0YWo5lDkj1XK7HynkI2dlEH8hHQZO2Fv4TrpM/yT@W0vYtbR3OmDCBsXWazZBIyrYlFUlEa8BX8S91/BxQX/Rl2uyzutd@@SDV2fzObMNM2x1@vB7QyBg9SSzxnIy3eB0vMICmvSmyQovEaz/vX5hDxjsz1jMJge6HUNT3rLu@3q3Jw@mDz@/NPgeoHX22eRaG/9byOnUglJaqyYp6i09XwMv7L8Zz/ZuEyfP21v/9k3R4qxga8jfH3n8jGan6v5Oxsbd@7dy@XSmqZx89PPn/7i3t5e7n46/7SR38lJmY3tP/2TjQ1N29aUjZbnqa144@TkM1HL5ET5z34Ubz99@nXPq2f/z2@8q6v4KMLjlBWBTsCVZSoY8VmCW0Ue60Ov2NsYtHI1NqdfOxa4n28wtb5T/C/fO3oTm8TqmvKpC@9J7E2sUIpxIxjAlg1sp7F6bBuDFS5jc6VWq4Gx@F/@LcSvfwxw0Ge@DY96PoBVmMfqUo2iXMTqBTComgbp/t/f@EYkh5xM1IiNC65d1oBLzBU1cacF1xZd2wKq/5QyihKEsyfDieEwtXRXvYsWEyzwsg38joIxacbwO/PsaJexZ41UKtWS2xJc8kuaJFJUVWuq6l0gB9KdrVpN2mJcwWk2m7@LStqTNKU1cGDENO5@@g9xxVY5Vn9ucM@EWGFj99X9eh3KlK1nt@opuvyORH2qWBIdZ1dkafYqDiJIo/XqEeNametipqSJ6XR6t032GeJKmoUtCS/@jMVCF@yy7KrbUhQI4rvGvny42AFef/6//fn3//x79Ps@3f8B9aPaPbOvbEGgU@gSdbh2K5VuvS7WXfG8ifY6tKNMpVQpKe3LZmILKFDrGVMzH13E89n4c/4NeJWxZpJiw0XJ1v3k0V6PLZzr3KUedfM9eGByYH4pyLCENTKHWLsWDoZWfye51DittyRkiGpSQy3kWxKPVQ@uMmvsQjWJWrEstupaXjtiu@0Zv9hw02NODCTDQoBHP7/1Rdnqoc/CVo86xepBtPoizJcNF@ZXiDUaSsugASFwY7sblY1SpVDRlHZ9/QVNM2qloIZhPPVip7Hw4piNLRAaC5vmVbegKkILC1ow@zLhoLI@ZLKbailbUMWqb9LaTKxCI9GykjZoixlVDHsbzu/DtQE/@sMVWvG5QS6@MwW5fm2wirqlZZX8ncKBhuPrLVc0rwKME6zb6XTedjvAdeh6R@/q6kSf6jN9rk86086sM@lOuwy7zPKMftbJOyVnxmb0l6VYNq9uxu5So37X2GDPOBVqsVRwNVO3Xi9kue0byeDgLUnOLCbE/gGuuqqpbAvGpww8gCkjI8jM@FNVgcWA0TpvvdtqvNuCDlpPbRNxbNUlP5fwktu7rZR0edkAc7Xq/7frobFKFzdB4VqXqdT2yzpwHy/rjRSAfOmDlCVGQOV2vbVNPmFifmq@93YL@Bcptd3Yrjn7dMvUQaQWQNxeyuXubkoG0y7ErG@CAJvalKQNHBIb/hABQVv1VFAYTDoBTML5@Yfc8ZwTLzi7K7xAzIM@fLl9Wb9sbF9ebm/Df5uel/4bXC@3r/3ptbjWhFn4t5CwNBtKvak0fVLRArus1NFFVppgqMMbwjWyWqnVQANccuu/zb@cXjxDF8xyS4ZcC7EtthVDXZ3Z2JYQe/X@i/8F7@b7L34fuUUGP6MixM6xUytbKGuWucgJD2Y/ttljftlgxjuwogs6PK6jo80fNi5HKcormVX4jH9CLRWSMg6/baffRvUfMnsFQa9RPiZqpYLYTqlzjcW2xUKRiN0vXLvi8fg/eqWVi3E@TYP6K155nvc4kstFPiFwVcuoknpR559o4F/T@YVV1z/6hXWXELsoM6MC@EkwjhghBu0opiiSBMNVfXuEBxxwoURCmfS09pn0Yk/CSRR9QstgXT5BUDs8qJXLdb7Gs/mUOs/W/S14qvA/2IBisGYfwjb7te4I2N9mP5vXmqjPPyZ13uDv0Vv8seMu/p69wR87fou/ZxP8sccd/B2/wd9eB3/HI/zde4O/x2/x92KAv@ZXslm1Km6eE2ZSalm93JyJhKFqbKfe/MrEnVcsw26YvZb/qapsrsySseZXjFnXGE8q3LEf/@l3v/nNeK0Wl@L0AaCc6rhMTcYYBsSvmDKWrEJNqBkVSujFq7vxrzRIRM@XWw0M0gJfIVZjm@qmmrEy3YzaUTtgMFnGZZlhZqj2VBJlMgbLzDNzlhk5ag9MBvwyYDIzfZYZsIydsSEY@IJp0s5M0NSH1wB@fQDkws/ELb0dNdNlkJCFTB19XlRtY8zMRbspNFicia8MkEVlVc7IBbOFH2VqiK9eNZWtllYuMRmbndxuvGrGW2JTREX9WjnHOnNjo/lKhKE7I/LmiS4s5nkg4FZjSrOpcEwCkgjRl5ft9sGT@@22gsNU87FztPgfHY2i1hv/oyPn8ZEzcuB/dHQEncuop3ZTQMd3d2tA1/3XTqxe3WlWaFgIhoaYsr3TrGclNBdSQPQ1dEt9yWsBEd71jaYQPwMB4wxkk2oCJJSz6mm1ekaGT7kVDG00o2P4P/MN/psgVEP55gyuUwJLNjSefdoMTdygfHoGTp8ykMvCPwiAUet/hb/539b/8QuWZIlGK5k4v9xO0JXEXzJ5fnl@6T/ryUTCtyS24YcOYMco55d1NFKgczA1EslW8vKSu8EzkdzmAOuQzHad4i7CwcARC5OkZPkj8V/3DUn7VzNeBb6Yy975DPWjmFhl@mLfTbM5y2SS1U7wDRJcRdYvaHNDskofoNzsNNTWn/6IvjOzk6RA@Vy1qm4xbtFyWrWaC2zFUrVaCiybiUT5@lXP7KgFkE9yuWSyWgXLTgA2A1aI22DvUqzGmvBs3b3LEylpFxcBzGyukMrgfqdqNUgpD8kant71afL54RF9ogVITT6G30bipCSRoQ884UcE42JFvHs30TNw33hvZy95965WzlxchC7jMTipS07tds902210z15ciG2R9smU82DPlC4u1Ew5pcaTjpt4gl@fhKQSksruaHVKtQyUXssVwdvPQH57u5Cr1ws5cCmU4klcc@ckHvIbF@NVMXZOZVBLRU4BxSo6R/cPQV/GcYKdX8aoQlkun0wAIU0Cl3gZw5@LNJePSPl8EjBzKfKQarnMgyZZrpAopcr@r7YBUjuwQfyHvFw2ldsqbu0CT4w/b7bqQppcPTdq6mXt3KjgrPtltet/xxvVnBh372bLgKJSptoU2u37e8d77XYNxjJkpeCBjkTdBdT@4sYr1V2qV7WUZ1CB3FGKw5DASoBlRdvKqyXEimD2UW0R4EDg4tMG2xA0euNDKHNUbYAjyDeQWg8u1mMdNsCLDVCaYyaz6GIW4/707HbDQA6/fN/QSnFJ4AtcjPAS/G6X5W0SRu2nj/b2D47T2rbEYtqDvf209vzFvZiK1vzCTt5ZtD872Lt/9AIiPH10sPf84KPDTw5ePAV3j50troDK@8/FO2paYT9jnwqv3be6YejG1DDaZ9Pp2Rv22jTbJtSeNYVCOQOXeUYbyjLWF@Wqwt01Pf31a90d08Xe//Db73/4373/ne@@/51vv/@d7//0i@9/G@4fw/1d/v7uvynn8fnTL/7Z777/7d8Bx/8A9x/B/ZOffvEb3@A32f8Y7v8Ucftj/46E47cAsH7lp19870c//eJXfwD3v/TvH1y/f@0nq@/vf2v9jfG@97s3h/nuv4X79zisIOx3f5u74fta@N/m4X71B@//xb/j/z/1f2j8nff/4o/x4Vv@6Q/@9D@9/@a/17TSn/7r99/63vtvffP9t77z/lv/WHv/G/9azUQfv/v@@3/wV3/4e3/1h/8j/X9Mz9/7kP/7H/zTv/hf/@J//4s/9O@fwP3vwPSTv/j30FX@9g9@iP/v/cHf/tEP8f8//6u//YNf/9tf@Z/I8Jvc8P/8y3/Dn3/9a//xb37rO3/1k2/8za//5G9@8w/@6v/41f/rN/7jX//3v//X/@Sb6PibP/mrP/qVv/zmt//yW//8L7/5xZrnt298fvEB7l/8A7h8eD4/BM6HlOvLunzxc@Xn74ONRSrQTqB1//L73/glaOD/grH33/4xngiEe83/x5pKYX7Mbf8fMGjXy4w@GTDB/evvv/1dRNH/ACiCf4iv74SWJR9u@c7CAmj9rRWRfvmnX/zzH5EtZlTqtIyDg3VJK6W2QKDZKpf9Adtf4YEov7QMLQTgp/QdpFBLft9B2vb@h994/6N//P6Hv/n@h7@Co7WUK6f30pJ6y/IYBMx/QDgMWPiQcBjwM0i/naKpNyn1Gdg2PsuXsrZtVz/77DOhfaHg0dPdC/YZ/NhnwcW4Fx5N9b0CP3THs6oM3BuvXrVwTTXipqgcuKLxt@@FW94hJUm7k9pRVI17GRfKJo/FquCQLWWb1Yq9m8mlilu63ozkW/WjbihM1dPZrayelnaUnJ9ELIVlTREzsxUwV/ksm6V8NMwYXzhCdwg02yLjDJ/kit4zAR@L/8I4E1iKZpP5mkZqYSSDH89PghuFPCSTmoXLVcTtMc5ubXEXWommdHNlhiWYzVIzEKPBACmkwOseMPS1Wgoj1nh@wMqzVi8xykoqVYNyY2weJ90uIYjZPYICMWupZ6y9VZvxiCmEVw/QkRLQ6ZmoamKqVLsPCdZm9xnCQuAE9tWrWr1Um9UR3DuOj9QsdY/yhMBqqVn9HdhrBBPiCbH77yArpVoqVS9hglhIXj3pNq@kPBWOyp5iKb8O4I0HCnZ2GbsjqiWRL0NsIMJ4aHymFqExIAQH/2Zqyy8O/QMj3VuE8A1Kyk@Fcf8dYnZ3OP@LAQCuJMmyzODGFf4dtgveMw4qRcnCK8UhpKhFUAsIHRjOMKWEFNVviiyQfqy29aUvBIaF2dzcFGJ1MSseyYQ6RWHuSYVOV@CGQxRQKkwslEV0NuioSZAXiF@l9DfjuHQXZxwwu5Pi9@7uFrsDxaT3wk1gUirr5JwYh7KdSokawK87KeElCDYCtFMCdCHIsxotFaaEdJoxuRZDP3Z0dORnghxe1oQUNHMtq6IdF6ym02kMYshyWk6n/bdMb3KQfYNMvv5b3kTk0gfemablqiB/VRk6saiwpIIQjY7v3r2DWqEdXJVDEF@Zv5lLy5XIExy4Sh/LmgdnkrRcWeCyPVMLOcYSNI0LV5Lh4ZsENKSkwHf@82wEVyKulUpxCgn4lxNbwe6@gkoNAmdxY3XManBxsbKUTwae@0ds/@jx44Mnx@NWiwkGfbLeaI9dp2t4XgL99p7c56c@tHIhGWs0EPRxRUMSIxxUMphQ6vD@s8PnFcaL7VdCgjJWpbVbv6BlVYiNx59ux/zdTSJ@ddERn@OzsihbQitnIWqsLsS6BgoruCiPQnSVVYXH3uCeM2OJTFoU02oBhcUkLkFCPn7RmTLUCcwVCEGvwrMg8vY2YUCon0u0QIJGqK@CUK/7@wKZKtSfHxxDhOMjpmoZWah/xmYyJihdCnWrZhn2YDLcxA12YjMjRsq02cik8adls/BUc4W0mi@2NjascwnTbFK1neNOyUuwnktYjK/CxYSvCuyr4AQXpIHbH5m/9/TwqOpvAETtewm@C1BU89DRkgJOl3Nwwjh6wSh0ZblJiG18/vmE1esgo0uHD4QY0IshC/bASWZPHspUzb2pa5DvgLGe@YmJn9OUe6Y3tvQ5dB7ARuzy8rIPkA4fMK2ukZXH6OHzsksuHTBfznQhZlcqtXdqrihoJ5XKu6ymCeAgbCm4yW4DGgDtVdhS@K/qQSLZbEkBWqWKIryy2ayA88@CUDEERvtR3mVqNYm3wWxOpe0oAn6hRZ/VtPDyw87uLMJmMzws@oAHG0xclgn8itzPtxUEsgHScAcefQ@86nfPzN27WZwIyeYy4YwHlZhdQt1sZnNZxDiecGrFckV/KUYUxVZMsIwJ69XAHGvCg0/qaWpMZGhDspEtZYRYI9YQ/v9@@atN2@N6NqNuK2Mw6mDMbSs6GDtgzG8rHTCaYCxvKyYYp/WsmtlWpnWBCdtccS9DvUA1cWLMUE84dxPrnmH1ZTz4VBMpAU3c9hXh14OI9V6t53SnuOek2pNN2zZcPMXPI@RyYtWxUaVkDZXLkN4DlkieC4PaGekaEIzaQEYtRa6tW0JP7ji9uexN5hYeIbIctxYHFjQeeCygG8DC4MTbTjabqzRYSx474x1ByxdTDTUDYw/eaimtpTeMnWKx0pO7lqG7O/lKvpTu4ekkfwluJ5@pDOTPHj96OJmMnxl0ZGknV4YIqNcPNXDtlCr5fKvREMVUg5Jp4TfMOV2TNjaAGBh6T4I3LtB5klZqQeSe6dZq8fhOVtUktZLNlC6FBeIQ51jCuoBRU1iyNOL93CcdFduxgUpV0nraPCcsVPr9/uXWeWphEfRzidsAP5eSnu6ch9aqFAlXYdO0ZC48wUXvA7rP/bXHiqjlS2K1UV3YiwWx2roUdkdGz9TxpFIzc349VgGoOYcag4SA57@suI4zqXSMvuMai4BZtRAE5Bm6HiAnXobJNTOY4vn15AqRQLPz61ByefEyjBVkS7i8BLxzZAPafa3MddrR21DLudYB0C5oPtuBwmYMFnv5UohtPfskW69DVZ/niloun8tr2UIhX9RgoCrnCiCIZdRMIZPXNICSK5fKxUto14ryLkbfY2T750F7r9AXKRJ6hatUbbRY8t0T0zovZSWej0SyenkZeyfE7jz7RIORde2VgNH6E02q17L5MpiyaNKykGEmaJqkZaWsKqlZ/N9i0PD/4eE1@Gv4hFhZTThGPUtPYLwFHsFmj1Bfy8Rhxw5@sWvA7hndNSH2hzptt953Hc/7e4S5p9sn3Ou@yZUbh14PdfxsoTcyJ8M1IV6MR6iiyXD/wSAcjDqQQSSHPMA9eLiW46wKUGQvnq4p5ePwcwKADP49AQj@7PCjh8eR9/HB3v5DocDuHT25f@WV9wPl2aODB8ehtch9g6j5EMQvHjx6dNXqv3JHL571p46Lt/Dg6EVu8Qid8DSvkINrOVDoTED8B1qJIwVWBGS4fDEwqAKeAbkLcvVd35gvLIwZNH7KjyqbXngmgZ9arwjHwfllnSGl7RisyzVxoaBPWjJ9IUAtlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlu4yp9/fAMehjmcxDeSELQtbIiZ95rhW78zsGRvCYzz2WVbxe/eYCeEhABlNu6TkAbgg1LkMo5rNcE2sY00NNh2ztY7wQic0uuZgCGPwmRMEEDq6zuD@shfEN6LX5GaHCU@D3K75WNeDCzFhN1bKi@K@KD7UJ3q96hrFl1UvU6mo8fhTVyyLYxiWdW9gHMyg5bIX0JN0d54WJ7L4gMnt2ABXWixnjAKMN24Ax1/WGq2d3EW9lMln//q3fvx3f/LrgxrNGzUz@xlpe@fxI2fC3iE7UfFyzlxnpYrdq@UrQPeAN2bE/vosskzCklYu5UvlrFZKl8qlXF4t5PNpVUuDpFksg6iRUUtqoZQvq@lSrgwsSq4Mvvly0WewlYCjVrYqANbu4sfZt0nekocgWPEFUvY2oSdZTA/tUyYaEEcUULid0KH3LbMGoytTMyxbZABRZ10We/BgP/PggSjeQwtuMNnPiGIPLflSJlO8J4oG@eyXkN0SHR6nhGouxQm3ZDL3AP1TDgC/ECGKQ7QcFHDeTxRNtOzvPXiA6fTRomF8CHbCfbjFCixFCGajBfh@AvAmhAbB9ng6OcroAVowSfR5wH32wU8UPwqygz7PeDAO4GFQ0r09UTzklr099NmnYud5Rr@Glj26RNEFC/QLURyAYeBCjxTFDhixd4hiF0zduQ5uIzDhRwTsiS6Kc44eRJAozii03j0RxXbgjsl84ucmj9itkEXlpd4lSxl/oqgFmcZg2dCSFcVcaMlB2R4@/EQfTnrGgF9zl7@7UNKHD7O6OZsePOh89FFnMOi4872Dj56h1/7@Q2BV5lO3M@j4ETttuByItf9Q009G86sXlPqw3a7o1kqvr7XbOd2@4tWetw3MIcR6AznzrwEmNGrvg9f@w/auvmqBmwC2kTCM4N3B694I3vf0DvcKLvKi96zTEavY/BWlmRBQmMCVauyOJ0Bo7fRI77pOFe2zGsukkZ@ZNwqZVpU82AiEgkz1Ev37CXzqOKeUPJ83ZrVMqzarFTW@Q6qfEJszLW@K6Y3RjlrOVzb0HVXLpWYV1Lvh9OMsLqk7LKHe3XrLEk@SOxoICGJzZ0cSG2prR1NLlULx5dZUFJMVfO5ki5W3iUw8wxg@ko1ia6eYj8QoFlO6olWKRWDTACcTGO07ONHTTiTODP0kmcTc0rQDFIHKyuZUTrPaT8zSsxrPF5snq7OaWuXKs1nmGrAefqlh2p04Lgc5AHCznUwFd0UkRLVcEiEDipJIJkOip4BpsX31068fnxwff0b8YN2fEXnqGki9qr71o4f78uFRYMNvLMgPkE11XHkfqdaSD@dXA6djEFDkhzDCgrAXuOH5Rtex5APa9ge8buARqHmSfX3H8vHDJTjPh84ZTxnVQ1RJaabdNRh@gsLsMb1WB5PeYwnKFdOTZzS2t@v1Wrs2Ig0KUMQg1tcYfZ9hAebQ43kPlVZQ9HM88@d7tGuZy2qnNovNAE67xiT11cjpvdJS3WoPvzxxr3YPI1fb8O5UjZrhuo4rgqgtVvs7dm1qe3rfeGq4qI7l8GgTOA08CJjoMyO5yZoHGHofxZhLqe4ye5GzJ9NRQpfqneSyE872hQ6InMTXg0Kf09nUdk0UL6v9Gku8hKBvwO5uskRPvpfcyVUBT/dYOwlOmVf9V32msUKuSmJIAmFBVyL8YLl1lqzVvwYvDvukUoHc@BV9AlAxMQBs9sgDQo/Ny2q3ZrGExGYsSUjKVQe1Bka/wMe2JIotSWpctIS6JH0q1KG/VucxveZNO/TRIpbpqFqmUJ2Bm1rMVYdQvfrLWdWtjaeuUbXA6k8S8mO4ehWQCrgDMG8vEu9/6RvJbSlf425VAnWBk0NtuV2bVW1UgwoNo5atgUeqkcukQcCHRzENY75WSKuFdDadS0tFdIUBP51PgyMIQMB3JKyEyJiYzswysppWDTWdyLwye6@S6ZME8DOENJZMT5wDezpi4AJVhW2TrPAG9KS0LQsEs57D9G2JGiuQjCoWDLA@ZGMzPURQzwzdohjJpMSyWwlrM4FhNo@n44NGq1I5mI2/Dl4J6c1OIVXMpN4mk9XERrLmGW@EelWoI3mhUo83oOX686fMm44aUMtgUotapdHoYBGLmXQ2k4XSme2LwbZYF1vpzEZBhSq6ZEQ2GKcb0SlF5HgWbuM2MuaWAVWnlrWqINP8XrakSWUlv5XP8DlGHlMY@@QNMckSTTE4cp6Ix4taPJ6MV3F9Y0P0p7OBphE9iwN1jd9Vd0RgxsSKWNYwwII00qniTJA7YMcuBWQWWQ7k3nPh8vxyuy58RXiOZ0W3tZf4K758vHeEv6@AUxmspZePXxy9OHogMIU2oQLnWd2oytV2FSySXN8VYhXGgJI2fX1YygZjX3Z7a2q7/pK/m3gAAuAKpNq8wVq07cwwUahjn6CuhR0WhzLo7qihadlWQyvC2AfUNAiqaWoVNUzF8ICFXFfoJF2umKWTdEJsdg6Z3U6R@9fYfK6npGBa4C7bHaQ2@cmgsriN8Qp@PL4Yt4mRTtunMYab6F9WT6snmfK2QMiNXdltX92r7Q2e7VWZmC0WxerefhuMYoLFqmLeB1rNPYw/ix/HD@PbybpYKpBreRen0VfPW9SBuzo5Uf3TS8VMW6zGWFvM@8cEI0eccuJ2uSng5vx47DzOYvFL@C2y@PJtcAKqADBOMtsvgR7GwuwkY0ESWlt8ybzqiaRmtqHJ7NIxUI0fA2Wx8CAoroD7y0fZXIEly8Hazlfiu7E4LqFUPO/d4oShD11ti/UYAwHlpBrbZmIpwMvbzElVLBZ8W1nM@QVM@kmA2IktOjig97VXGnSmmO0EDiBq4jQgDPb5PK5YxJRXY@9zrZR9fHhk33cfRI6KvcQMQA7w3Fu18rK9caJCJ8qK2ZN0jO3G6LSEWIb0Ne4ACD9havUlIp6JL@4fPRZziCwQ2sApAYXiuYZEmxsXGw4uUbFw8@U7@@OvMzaOZ3O4ebEWm9Vy/sZ/tV6X1G0N1fIVWQWGzL5akDIXdU4U6uRR0MDn/S/9IDfbLoFdy6hg17R8SqvX1S2NJWPj91/8PipYOj/4ZO8Ri@PCxt/9yY@04t/9yb@i7YTxS1rs0LLFGIREo1ooxs7Px@fnl3Bxv3ysFbu2i6IFlamoerm4JUNplJIOhrYS4xUCTGJRTcY8KebvGS3kpURCVbTkVraUSYLPha9ALaFlSmAN1vvISSzkxWTs4JmZ19Td7R0o2U42p1U3oKWp4YFjFv62Da8cE2Klx68uGANLt94bDEyNTIrCKu8ktv1O2mbvcKntnbTBXtXquAtExWPKwVLUFh7bxAXZeD2lbMUZCJes3risXrZStJYFEvpLw9iym1fw0NzAkzvLTls2/Iwtj34YKXDwwBrYjK3XnpjYSipKryde79nbBsvXoalsKYvD1GwrWKHiP0lqJt//0m9oWuHv/uTXLtoX7c80ENDL5YKqxX72s@2pPfWMXv1nAOAGtTqBkE18Nuq/QUMonDOuVtb0Y4UGuSsKsamNgggPH4jqKJwzYOLMgW30SFQXTpHxpJptc82OvQQF20KtG2kSZEiTWrIqCAHHzwUVd9BNEwy2hbqQG62kcC58Fb2Ar2Eg7FSFry5AgcMIOBmn2/asqTumk08Jiqe20uwuRIEUvopaMzdIW4g/KEpqlSlb16PyLHuENWJS2cjwPNTBCeO58FWI4iuMt@ZsrKNiGwxp2jAKyxiE8kkevQak3YK0LR6hTa4JKj0PkGY8dzySDcKM8FXgywgLJrBrzNyGAFWgXF8FBEAZEj5gs8W2WTbJzs1UqrpQ8HmJJzBQiakeKNUQMBpC66ESlyByFcOBEwhR@IlibBd@DQO3HHEMgHAYfLtFDcQwjE425IBJ680HgwJYpGEuQUVjd@8uclWrmb0koxIh/BNzjDOMVA/26rwCsECEvdOriGmGqlOrgWvY7ADjKcoutDqJ60ytRqIyEa2XggD/D2602CKvVBV5VLEAfn3xXtEFlEFkRDuvwy7brjFVKyZZmPku5L1LmSLVBqFc3pzdkbXPAs9LyOHPYsEHwIBoHUdnbf12e1WrCgOpZYpfX0LdepwY@NpQuPY8JH6HkyB2GAuKYloUum@6IDHSPpBAcWciqyYx2kLRKeWDzkhoOYZHFfJJfFEsDM3graMCSj@dDVKc1XWgQr2xY5PGStKohedEoEUAjfKV/fFsT@0z/FqfXzcUOZojjxT9YcvHHJMGTgdVE1Fc3IbRcQ39JMBNmhkDmXVHPaaVWYIaGikltENwSYpEGe6A4IE47ljGCLL03DDo/KFXUZQBMKPTDmlmfGxCuxo@MGEEsj3lPkewcmaemMoxqs2WnD4eU@R6bmLIv2L34zs@fC2IluOcMMs8MfhkfGJJS5DHQPQC6SENmF3cgNgKbibSsmmcAVLTPBTcRXgVubGUjsTdSMyT199ZdSPRxhq9oPHGhFqxjFPdjuCXrgvBn3Pw5l6gZ4y0ZYFdDkmu4WsYqsVRd0ioOkvwNabVSFmXjIs844QYEwNNY2gUxq5xynD2QMAxBohmN9DZg70YSvtVGgCo70HPQgWkE7eCmqYgJ24v0YWu5xN4m91hWU3AgFwNnK@yDWBg1deWoYMfRMVyeJMeVIxMKxtIV6B3jnrghzpO/OaH8YPWjWZSDrto3mzDB4eDDqVVY7xbBJZ8xIK9A9szFX0DPAuQwxU52UiIKQCbEpMiBx3Gvxqdt3aBaEmFXYeUZgjBRzVAIVZBR5KDGiYjn9UTwOOe7vFvr/jqSc/OzmTSmTt1Tdnw8FNznmPrljIemMB0O8rEGI39j3qbXWUcwF2YJP6FSXk8HO/MkK@tle/O@VsQ@l7N35CViPe9OA6Op/gltcGI9OuhYjuPGtQDk77C2E34@8N4@9Na6fOg/VWw/Uml@CUCAXkNwMzS83Q3DcDSne5Jun/Wq/oep9QhATjUohE4oiZrN7CMvMBkjvthCGeCdDT06lgntFQOkEQ@Vb5ImpcwCDkPrL59bM4gkm2csT3X1ecJ8k9iaGzAiTmxPWwOwz75gBH10p9ztcrmrDFvLUWfhdFhUAs3irioPE84vxko17GN/jPuPwP/GfefLRINkm3MWpwlQ6dLLA62etS5GoREMPMgzCXXR73wIcjAj4MwRW4Ycr7kdgl3t0axA3xzG9RjLWgY0CbGgHAjoTReNhvNlu0ZZ1utlDKAxi4SIqDGAXSjRTg964VmxL51ao0db8nJRlW7MCr5@Uan7tBvDbytYBnDCqKGwfFlonbUwcjf0cIZAr/AAAH5MPBE1mBvkjCT1VCpO3lCw2mICxzzjDX8zLSI@/K9fDdglzjqOWKjgFoRQOgeFgmyCT4s6Dn8w6IBdfjUdSBMEFaibyGOUEtfvBUHTF7pKpzWVKmSIrmSpCCbgHZkV2tXixL4Q1U0rnhFinnp1380@xtfOvt96Berc08Nlg8YVSHaVXD3KbAQfnchrLJ6LVKvkANlS7cMF0auA86f@qM1JLOlBGIGTweL4J2Zk@4wEan8bpLXD52TFW2xEjaFea0GRZzXeLfk/SJAKUd4GM3zo82DhuDH5wQEYGRWRjP8aLNotFmtxgkHm62JdhbJ5IwyOeNReOjZmky2/GggPR0GwwtWTwu4U9weKwI8lQ@jwAaNRebppwbuO3iNGkRxecZPc0FzqBX4bQhZbGxn3dbK1BuRTEeI1hUA2BCvAejxb5RXhKsET5VCW0ijOCoDGsVtfjPgtAIaGJHgKteynQgbGcnAwPCLKRoHoO@KqYYgqjTFjr8Mv8V04Bjc6nXHzHJIddkxk77y@wdxbCFmIx00wn2omRwSZJRkXti@etoozxFje1MQcICr65w5LLGC2QZ3ZepHVTqW01FGOu4fwi8Xc1d5PE8G8gMuUrHdsTPRJ04uV@FCk0nNblX6XGYwB7aDHzyLaNoHXq/nGJ4dn0Cldp2BbXpGmqES1BPDFzsM/@shQpRP9o2OJwj@TjYuxiJo3q6Q1W23TductNsJ3CCarITb5Gm/KDbPeFxA@RdMkfhAnnygR@OE03ltdCfJ22HiZyP8aMdm9yRxNPY9UTnIHgMa1gX@H3yHwMEwz/l/u/u@9bZxZM9r6ykQ2WmTCUVJTuwkcuSObMuJphM7x3aSyTpuNS1RNjuypBblP@ok851zLvYFdu/3EfZVzjucq32K2fpVASQoybLTPbuz3@brtkgCKBQKhUIBKFSlK0d2SQ9V@mTkcMSUs/55/5S0vovYxy5zbgJ8I4UNhILBgHHxVIAlbcUKHsKjxGl5gauL/vTdRdVPK07gJuVXsgAyxPDUcJLGoOxwRnXNG6uTYqa@g@/H98DG92A@vrwKn8RZluZVSfy@qh85KQTKmKLx6HY00HSSW@0pdDKoJJ@hV0mBO6PYZvu8NjCtUdaazu53iD@85C2mtwTx9zfRf34HmuL1u3ZfQMNeHYxJ3pzD1NXhGJWxOWt2KHvDheyZri5h7e071kV5ER54ByoEqbEsuHrwpk0Dc0DL7jjZQDaAb@F5mMRN8T3byVUlcQZOw0tPfV65uYu2m@2wG4zDtqNzehZc0@J9WrCxvLpbwyHoWOj1Za3n0NzlJqk0jYPokqlyA8sE3qXr3sxWkiVKuId3yhnDxs30Q/qUaMYWX1V2q2kdsLy8iO3Yywjbn4PxYCwBG7oSoFDLUZl/pCfh6@N2ghAdZPYse2m17jzxue8kTbrDjJDk9bNNhj91AxFetqb78PtIdHtLqXOtQlXTy7lsqKLZPR7N63GLKwxPyrHT3VjyNqa7M89ZrCbAUhG29X1TyBRkGMi0Wo4NUb7M7bF@b0om4Bvv0/VumFWaMwRqUpIl3Sji5TbrF24OK@MG/WLD6T39AuBpOGoKQ5m2YU9Lx/xVnHIeDCytRX8hJZ2gWFQUkms0rFw580zZv3xL6mzdWGdrqs5Wps5kBGSrtDLlWpkqdS@ge@Z1QTfsjG6QzkjC2pl@5olt@tfrB0PsVnxZjpYrkaeWL5crJJCXw@VK3SGhvNxermzzQ7xcOeCHz8uVn@ghHVvLX5crZlggw5Be@eEFvmsRjvfWcmXLcb/lRsHnMDb1@suVpE8pz4/yyhQhUqDdpDXiiK3X180cDUOa2Fip9BQ4JvawfOJ9GI//L9F/EnyMwxIhEXucDzizeqjKmUnDmjGkHpo2TNiLGSO5omfz@t4OG5glWVDNQ1rj2WUYPKnhi8tZYSSIIZVPNOiXEITcrMzGSFkz2R3R0bUTh3InZ@tn6vmsD7QdTj@izMdpJRxxTpc3/ZUFIR14NzxR@CY8p9Ax1TFGOJN1Z6AFov6yPKdR6OssLrr37R7ive5sJsK2YLJILzFYS6aTDseHc6hs0B9kmYRTccshssvwppwMSnDvRDGWCnpk3pDMn3XLIBjswe/Oa45VDqhlRBASj0rHMsqSeYFlMZJSWWdpqjL4CAVL5tAID1ufOZrftn7kfCJuPJ4rbpqGTFmpkiVXVkxSYR@@yy6CkdSeLF7r8Gj2fctXU/Iaey0OAFglk1pEvva/Q3/vi/5uFGpDhIkKZinWs6fSafV67iw7gXk3rXa6A5HoqW13pnKU1JCSnFYHlmY@j9emVHyYfIiSL5Um0Ce0fUO2ZE1wC90m1xYCC1rC8DL78fMKffy8cjOhpjWS7qVvlBYfNWk40vAE07Rp83GVhs/qYqTw/nbQ/e4OHmY72O48wOMGDCdILqN8eNFjK5d0bJPYli8QqeWKEkHOx6VJN6cfSdzz0W1ybEsf9pr723u7rz/SpPvkyRNXz9HjFD@MWuy1JvO4QGZr9WQ@mLFsWfEQcguH3diOj8/6w9G9T738lCwRYU3KQEC1GPbTY9zVssyS5xNjl8pJXouiGtbndBgEGakEVSfAlB1puo6IIOHIeRBoIEa9JXp7vFpzObhUs9kLzsNmk6cvE69cz2LoGnMi7v598V7xIh5yXG6JjHaVy7ELELW9pz68qh2qw1d1tfNu6yf1ce@d@lDbPYTvh7fvNl83thT9X989qKtcxhQPUSSxoCS6boetELGB1Uqp9Fgx5K3@YCxyx9ly5ftBcK5e9Vshjqmex8H5izN58XvhaENK1Wk5OsYeZsRRQ8@jEewtOMwlLWOh3LT5ZiauVyjKe0Jr2nOsec/77agTUd4c1r6DKIzNZT7VjagHSd6a@@yeKEmIaMmmQxypFhZYV1Q8oPw4uyEwgdhfgcTIISEw277ShEv@fTcFD@v7bw4U3Ihs7e1uNw4be7sHamdvn17ffmzsviR6Ng4O9xub75DEGd/sbTd2Gls1/iAIlHwF/x6/XsSjuSj4yM5UaX3Gybc/oO5P3rK73tDg1VXAd1RjtXzRg/SJgm70e9heXs9dxFBfcC@WjwqUs1Tbf/me5nwV/oYTTnMUzPYH@XcxR1ldKqnnXBsNlg0ab@t6uNK0Vyi7fB5xPlYItBSus98Ph589ZYCzEU87ClV@CzYq2PsW9yA8lg1oqugewQYoY7BSVRwgbXnZe84gN6i2VrcPf7BSmxgR6hcUfWFMTdZzTDFtKwOguEDS6GE/qLyefCC@pw8rutrRUDKoR8kHyaAeyweoog3YjqhVneNitHcB8azW5MOv54MdPhZWT5IPmwGvYp9qnKTfuEsDlQSYhLOULofBk10eDtUbxK0o4iIx50eIuG5XBkYowUlJJspRItu2Uc48CZsOjhq02ZsE/UYqcQPshILOKFZO1fXVIYyDwl4kAQhPu0FPTKBS0x3mPfUUnqmq@gp8lATu4ys5gz4zIIKGZvFIym1rrTC8azkquTlVY6BtJDl4rjFBuw2BzSkE/ggYAlTIrHRaPFPxtWGA6Xc0KztxnzgS@7Z/s/MTO7cvWmGmgLbacn6Nfv/d1UT2MuskY6fI2FEX/R4OSa3ko8xOf0hjnMUqhzqDFGyd9QejSPrQybaAT5x4mqPcmNiotl@qG5naQIfJGnv9nlXpCXHxDbWeEFPepVbmeDk7T8RXGgObOJ8mYbG7AzrBSf8ytM7OPBwiXYXYfiFFmM/Ksfk5HjEmon/mUtnxN4XQuU@rG9ubnwp/@8VD/FwRCxK@2hgd4n9iTNRFw4PP@dhgcQi9S480E/cwvjhBaW2Dp6UlRrkBRuvAs4jWdS@a60mamBtPf8d1pcnv/PHr16qUKkAy6Zjn8ZmTSjdPHZkqPS5zrLQJiCU7CVmS9Y754jHMRF6/wBUl9AIcLfUgR7Bun4gqqEWIad3JRYckiw7urLs7ge@qDbaoMIqk@Maw@6P4s7NZfbjhFlODEmWR0zEi2jOQy65rmaXwfDUFbns@OJLfdwf3dC52Mj18F7TtudC@C7fCw5thybRkwbo72L/NASuT2x8CS233bgYsk@Q0tITTE@b0lhYTa9r5Nf4y1Xc89ggM5l7soCRArdouenxEbbyrO1LAtcGkCtHB4XZ9f1/lZX1CZUnuYcnQ1mIQsO@pt6m1bdRjYecnSlOyWE6UJ/MlY9Fm/s0bzDOJd4Oo0DqIp@mRCIvUh3snuhapp2cWViHY@p4FoqFcFrsvRgbFRxrwN1oDErJpp1kNzM1s5qJMPlFsG4FrunmiG9s2/GxhLXM3QiYPxzYg2yYoOMXNktn990H044qpRxQsOJlCg9ukSdN8Q@uEA6p4QBl9P9uDc7rFdCmM7EXBXjS0g@FXKath/3mGYkYSJVx0YUusa@VYoyb68ZJRc9ggEdNAAEtPnSgWzZRgRDx/eW53qJtOek52CiIlE0F0X9hcQcWPv@kpjKmRzJPVRCG3x9oSY3NksDzG7qyGvX5zpvuwhV6bFA@TVZG0nVtV4R9TlcwSmZoMzWc2xiQS5LXV1Ue3wZ5shSle@LOwZQ6ZlJ@j8wGt71OQ8Tjm7X3i3MauZ9JTBphDOjGtNwNmoiCpOjPmlEzbeTKy8SNcZF@IkEGEAsQlnqzVVdcTuM2GLjOSDZ2zTLXBGsJJQ2XUTFH/2/zqIJBvre/e99cngw2ZYDr4DVb5b/rDOExv5Vk@c6xP8DWQ/RYOhz3OJveZzgHF4WtMcy/b8W07MXiVViGRz9vslnT07SQxu/XMXgNXwtuLPkKRY3dvfXJ7r1Bet5u603hdVw/YvWgnsxeZH@ZdS/bci3rzEGAZzPsSmD74Dt/9uEL/Ew6eAUlk4tt8DtPGvRU3pghpzUccs0qbhWrZWp7s/U7cCnrwsuLl78cq7/1ABXkXtr63487aWS@tZ8oTcvGg51ApL1/w81yUvmFDF5CyIKQ38d2asHBTw1hK4nrNaR/2UTjYCq9l94wtJ4Ni@Wlp7VmOW9fzRt750bNj70Grmlc0@Qa98/hieNX@fNo/u@yorhr8enLdGv/@m1Krj9UjqmvlB/HyXF6rFtmt7hP6@1Q9KzHnagR/5EvyCI3tS8xgpZZVug5fv6dcfuBFcwU3JCa4VD04N1yIK3aj6vnR2nG1Vy2tnx/1jtdxyW/0sDp6WH7o4MMPNIuSjJGT@aPRMeZUe9c17F0qeFLl2LT6aojiqyH05U0wjPqva7svM7txUACwBaZtvXlDXcKQL8CaDXdP/F545ehtMk@BY3NQkHILfCuoDGcAvJ@M7Zh2RJhRr3ikzcbX/Hfs5hZK/sVg1OcU4/4SrKW@Rl9zC@YaU4l3FCjLUWScZOJ@AcFJ8zg4GJKvY7GiLpRFXSvj7qRrgThCSRaH@U/5PO4UAlF9l@voOBf7YdA6AxJdUqu/cjH1/LnCG7Fa7PMuHkw5giFfmCgd4xEHIPQz4NMGVMGae8zXPnLUfLyX8SBfeI9qxPdk2EA@x5oiUmD@rb7w/SYu/5wIIIRfEJ3L11ucWvMiRVLuDvLmAnzLZRf@OGbAtUrplAU0FrClvmoKnC3FmUaoVpOJvi9cgZxCK/qnW1Ao89tUM5L8rmRnkvA5tX6LQUvuUk7awE83LeZYxQqmmMlskWLhVmpgp4uWR29CGlZjtRV2u4S00GIhJQce@X6vrv9hUn98hDqPE@QlvTCVXsik@5IuSKW5fJrg00wVO1N@8Uua75vKp9m8qbqqipUXn3q65ZNKkuZdn5c39kf9ZpRm3ki6UrgySXieSShYKT/P6H1JuZcpkzB4kn4k6Zq/V3TPJ1hm8r7I1o/fnO6gkI1nta3JBJf6vaj7Y06HbNcpYLM8UVMpKc7BOJUZVFV9B1OLE9LgsM/Pw3ajmkJ5WDYSh8dMfuP5i7yvlYwfnUk05Bbj1MCaMUYsKnGdD5lw13xhkerh5HsWCIYJRlNm5G6YwmNdeGyBRa57plq5BTk1wKlpk0O8inuRX/HHDPYscibf4uzEBcH8Whovt5uzBGKhey8/m0xZaYLrIvJRN2rOLJLWPZ6EOFtI7Fq7wEmdodzB7mAb/F4iJ2xBYSTFFN2TFE3pNEPZsO9NXYjEb7m/Fx/kXgakYw@64bWqYZkR8C2sXOaC@yiMRzH8bLELoPhiMOji1JEVviu@Qq0DF6ys4rglhWjN7H6uAcseye/hSV9Ip0K@2gPkKxiIpAnxxekpLpPhBmz/CqIVOy7RyM/VemPZ0KAx82hFrpmHCs43WAB3o1MbCek5GT2gdDwIWqGfIx0tJu0nJ03tRDqGLe@n494I3LnRlFbJ5f7lImp93nqJ89wn5dKjskWyS30cXPIfPU4vWBGRTMIKPDKulh/nctbZcEvOhgsA6KnXmOjfE2@Gl2GvF@ZqNGNwxpiU1jgcXoZtP5fbD5NDYMAFK@NkEvew@xfDlmzukNIVEDPilnDsyXEYcRh@MT/LcXGLz8q8HA6t0tNm6urLqA0CmhsnnT5Oh/nAAm4ChB4odB6OiCgPXJVFic@eNS6su5xjI4qoAT8n1tlEQoZefxS1qGd4JyvXJVByDJJW1mtPYEL1tboBLgf7sxDA9ZiUAgYBc5Q0D4ecPjT/LhyUbpg5Yw9MzxRJ@vV5rNBwD4cRSd@UwNwrXMzCnTr48FXjQB3s7Rx@qO3XFT2/3d9739iub6vNj3zGjYNydnysXu29JumSnKbLqfkefcjXDqhknhNytd2Pqv7Xt/v1gwO1t68ab96@bhA0Ar9f2z1s1A881djdev1um0/fCYLa3TtUrxtvGoeU7XDP41pNsVxaTu3tqDf1/a1X9FrbbLxuHH7kGncah7uoDKf6NfW2tn/Y2Hr3urav3r7bf7t3UFdoWG67cbD1utZ4U9/2qX6qU9Xf13cP1cGr2uvXEw3d@7Bb31dsJGC1crNOWNY2aQmLmrid2439@tYhGpQ@bRHxCMHXnjp4W99q4KH@1zo1p7b/0dNAD@r/8o4yUaLarr2pvaTG5ZxbqEL9svVuvw73SaDEwbvNg8PG4bvDunq5t7fNtD6o779vbNUP1lXu9d4BE@zdQd1TCJ/JVRMMohal0/Pmu4MG062xe0hzxru3sHdwqZM/EGEIyxoV3WYCwwwCrSUi7e1/BFTQgTvAUx9e1en7PmjK1KqBCrCo2Dq0s1GFRMRDu5lqt/7ydeNlfXerjuQ9gPnQOKi71GGNA2RowCDjI7EOVfqOW41@IrzkkZg1ZzjX4@5UjR1V237fAOY6N3HAQUNzC5Nt65WmuQ/fx9YmStTHnkFwbm@sdKY/XYbw9jm9IzN7jybxmLS1t12nGVk7u8qnCe9o1nk64UrJTqOZJkmk14zLmnZ4cnHajHqdPu6YJsVk4@M8PvUQ0slFNJxPuTmh0vT@ChdYXGw239eatNA9aDZd7y4lM2jcVkJvg8/L5eo2IugFVt7Y@KlUhO7PM4Ta@EEfdLKhHg4gkFOo/4OYvgXnoauKxXaoi@HyPgCbraNYjk3OcJRCopEvOyKMT1ol70zwe6TZgQs6BrzfamKfFJaRnKkf05/e1/RFJgfrA0ln2e4qFrGIZTSi30NTjVTCLhH4j/ZIEHW4Sj8Ow8@nTsmuDmt@/7Tfbzuua8pw3hGtA08d95biJ@HpRPHCZHlGlo@ddbyI2Ky7WYVJzp81yZTuF3/ILXPwpzniH9dgIz4fsGvKVfFmtd60dH6Q4rBI8pR2bYHrFdzJ0Pne1P7a@IDVXGnl8frE91fJdxlbsBeEX2Ca8I643DH/vDqWDDTA2BcHkSTSHjKKRauMsTdJMl9RxjNkuorasPyhufos5HmdSEKK7EXQtevEbDyMrm3sSQ6/3K@92Xy3s0OiE9g@frr6ZG09l7jd@qsnvx9RD7vuZa9jA5rHSU/jJGuUbJHiwyPF8pyesj8zcLGIjHCYbzqNP8LPQ2K3kbVkgiBDc2PEtOrBRC8fgg55xQ447uUMv84cmZoBnExTXbTmPLhmFT8gXYl5QBuzdMfca9f4A9jJ8DdDPGmQZiDNYuzMmDiXVhcs9/I7xlSUFzfsuAdZ/LzhY3HjltCAt7rYfha3a/lN87bVi7GYMmK8crdzSULi3iQWythV9GRkv2U/I3oDmL2H0Ze/an6jx4/awR27uwviUW10QGTcSUpinzrdjNaNPtKQjxHABE7VTE3PFXb5XY0Ujz29nZw4BrFGA6OCaDyw8c0CXk/8iExWyRawL5Zd9UU4Fc47AGddc6x@J86d1RwNZd34D9HvxiuFEliJkxOh2lVSR85k@Zj4sTDkzJDpT9GD4f8TaTID/nNacRL0lFqWE8A7UZKhCq1o@cpEia7MQYN1upFS0/70MQXzze6Ys6Rh@vTmWu7XEAl074zNh4/s9rDjzCAAmBwbG/b4TUzSzgJaOr3Iu7o4zkl6rfOBo/RcYaaKKbiFtWOP1S7PnK3gxVWu7DVZFb6mouqFLNxOeNTTkmliKa/ux3kB5xr/H8UHvAGSDHjm0jOxWp3krJIeZUYOaFdL1oTTTjwmkVr67cZTuwfKcpGZkf365MsQikBvAJ/pdnIkl74S89ysx0WeidUhe8GDg3YskzH5aJd1J2yI2Q0B536bN0MQ7GV0hQmiK9DZVV8KTTn32VAElaRWh6mfQYhb1yfS8rR6lWDPO5Pg0AT7dz2JDRDKrpbJ4YuDD42hfV3eV2@CMaHcvVuzhcWKDw76HmwXUZlsS@jyCGzT6veHpDoGaDfh6EVj11cf9KZD2Isvhtp/Ic1n0VDvSBiln6qB2iSrd55mxCk/oxZHI9xWaPvMH9yk8xAWouKe5LqwphxiXsOjG2bTMbp@WFbO8zTlOdGE3ZIyEZ@rNfX1q@QSgmqXoSFTMIqTxQXbbHI9OHdIht9Vf/gZcz9UoF47bCeeSS2QvBcondTosY/H1kiaPujHvKNBXYEdkIQSZdlISwxVaY5@otlJ2zXlU@@Y8F3KLfn@ehImNdZSVFHKuLp2Yr61AnUmqLSiXYMmzkLLK6uMyqwF17cbF2PsLTR7bK3yn3qJSKmIElG9b1RHPIncTJ4@4klv8lfvxxg99AVn3FoFBcLQWXGuOi3nGD/YFHyIwmHb3hMlTaYdDLD9xkuffo950Wwdard/rWAUh2NaAbSK0XWRYTSdv/TPes2tfjc4jfpRQOs0eNS/FomHxzE/osNOh/2rmGM2SSBKK1N7nD6Lfxlxw4b35Fxy3XLNFY/CgWObKYyG49qZuIngnXMYAaaBZpm/B5M@0pIyj1fTQrns/VO2xyu76zeWfVSeVVhO9AFAC7iNCQsKuUM64otJ1uXT9akMJ/MyWDieqIIK3Bss9jIYPyMS8TFMBmODzJRZgt0IrMxuxPiofe212QfhEI6Wwu0QIYZihz97AaJ3kxT5EZYCFVV@WrKKyinKNfwQ4mF8M7lXnvyTsScE/gT65UezuGUWI7CI6xhvS7GsV7SXUcKFzQMjltEsiUmKRadRz7p@yPE8riehZpPHN1GDLX9IKdJu9qa4EiPSoYUPQgs6TRI5zbGLSWVZLbvstwMqSG3klG5m2PA2@1ke/DjElZ0zCKYtDdmxkL6JVC2iEqIjT5jX2iiLT@XbR8zKyl17bYKA1VkmZ1acbidvNBe@gRLJ/Ipjrf6QhHF@gnra1GM5HvUHy3ek3o2yY6Zntlm0brnurYbAwmxVmiwftJm01TEex@u5SXwmmCZLMbY0Ix7C8pWfEzafJOJ1tYnxVm2Ob6HDTTRL7aaSSSXp77aMfUyKl7DoNRNNMqQYdzgpXU@@HzWp4c2bJYiGKcurJkuMJkRGcyyPFqgJMiVUujuFmPs07hP0aBPlUG@baGf3z41EnTSSMy5PTVLGySXoCcftuLRJcmnQgfEF3MSJhpsIqUThvPbGfJRXLpzAyTASBCC04rCQ7kPJDm7aWRN8xNEBOk4T1kJlSCJ62rAtHBKn/wnB2Cu/3tzRFg/NcaF8vC6QrhNItKrgXPMgmfvm9HrUvGYoU6SgIT6DFEmLpmTT2d1b9WfbQvkIgpTmZG3pW/LQGFc9JGzoj53UvIYOnFalS2ZGVHYgNFk00FigVcppN5TlKrS/aCgcD@sGPYxoASGfHfw81CXgznutlFAbRa7bY2RxNblltLmqsCFFUoaSd5BfD0VRdXnhSgBCwZjKV8sEAW5NGXscCrDrHZvzMojqPqKC1TKGJX1kr6ipneeMdBBVZ3i8auUozcrxzIZRmAmEFIvZeVJESGeZnSWFQhPdTFysHE9mtyfNQQqx4X2hOHWF7pUsDZOeEwJydO@Sm0qUo7LySpqDOfHxqptJTPibU5@VrNTSZCrRJ8HwqFCeTH1ayqRmql1ZyRbNlCR6uHatmUQihWsjnEiFP/ePr6bYLs8Tm1BrkZHRMrR9NqKv0yqT1m3@r7F6zpeyjY5h4Nk3w83yqykhVjJO2ec7YFfLfGQA3@1/urXGMtVgomMFsF86c9nFkQUha6x5TPVoFla6xtNe4qDArGn7HfX@cGcn4/b1ZGwMjc7D4WqpVAITn9jO741tNbaSon4xm7vYueh2i4OrvwzfnxRZ9ochhwSomBV0SF1CgyL2@8NTiQwBHCgrchf0RVas9S86HTsEA04o0XnUbZJTe0NQPAFFidHL@0PeAGKQeoL9BQ1E@35Ryei7CkTR1FDMMRSVhknwZd6cnhF58KED@@zkpIqBQTAbayaat9zqxhfMIIhswp3F7ovdL6l5cv5V2O32PfUBUZ/hKWDh22SBnR27QEmy4ISRb/dexOyP1lPhZdS17hUji83rAGcmJhNnwviFh2/8/fC0fj1w8kc/52laoSY/RDMfwj@1p/KneVc7i78DWOFDQvtOuc@DgdNiOk1mpqlej@D0iTB6VPZmrn0yWVzeE9M0uz03iDobXZ@dNVDTXdYFjC977l5uyQ3ZE@LmP12XO6BhSWBonOBz5W4lcNXsnycWL0edzt2kIocBkI79LokokVD@nEDkMwAegXr4ET3hRfunAg3rnQmHIqLgIFjHtNxBgSYK5HL3W9XfrpxaraaWBg8fqlptkx4KBVXbrKltfNjcVNv0von3H6orq6vrInO33S/0cdN8/KY2CQbvcD5snQ236ZXSqrg3BmttdPFSsbrkrS81q8831uPiUW0T1/rp6T//7b/@57//t2JNv/wPvGzyy9HPSSbf94tLrS9LP3xbx/vR9vHy0snR0uB4@XQdXPZ39hreb4wKQWo@6g9PcosyC1hf2Y7UrLPZ@4wuqkzYwPNg@JmkS0UttuLiov4aS@QolrGLrdD6HuIe5Qkt4U3QgcmlPCGxSEDH2I6n3mmFMMCj@YYoSbjADlTKy9mK2biHO5gkQ3Kqsqg98bDOehniTkvqSQF3cWnGKkS9OOxhB/ySdV5pXi4X0G80amr@Lf78Jj7d7F@rB58c9aCkHnjqQT7PP@W1Z/TVXSpGuJ0r2Wg5kM97lJIeLcDMUMURK3q8fuBYOxPkzuWWOGQPIBk3FZxZbsF5yeqPL8tIwLX4NLeAqKZKtkj4kAlFFr8s9b5Rt3yhHN/ymas2rCg09SqGK7NOVJL@hQoUxGIIkNZ8LgSp9KlKnPTxjWQ8Fc0X3dc5jibEgEHW/Zc7PO7xgeaipZ62ec6spRDmiM3n5SvmxnW5DM1oI0XqTxHgAxVZTpb4JuHy4nJOrLytVnIz5Ra23T7NfGLrMA5HxjZdCv1NWUwg1tw24ZZ6@l6LNuSW4xWVj5LjFauq/KTtt8pZRc4vuqNooK8rcO0YUF@S2r7JSEKPMiCBIz77K9MjjDcKjKeoiW6RYFlj1e6j6TISevpqOnWw68vJkUWE4s8Oje2vE2PbLfItEcMOwgOMVGLK1wmibqy9rgyZ2KfB8ATRAYMOB1QbybkZ7@chOu0Exv1OgrTPkNnkPB3P1JTFwTA4PQ88tbjbPxwG4wZNW6T5jFq@Sy2ECyYggcGnq57VPIOwtEh3CVMkaQpbDiF4QXesw6NJ3@aTOyfoUjMUtNsVDIIMOzElw6@ZvpqgY8rV39EJNspTwjs5jdQiliUvLI00pLx9bYaH2dTQyZka7LGTDJx8TlBNRqbhBV3oAhPtOR/8kiTvwkeArjuvbwHqqwhrz1A/ZqfTsBdkJqdBN2cu@hfXlcyLGM8cilKskXIaypNyGvEOWJEe@XPWC4TMTcadUW7BcRY@xTqc26I9j7CT78QWvxioKAlAxwHM@GaIeteLRFhOzFBpDAxfNdjynyB0usEp4Te@CsZgxU@Lzo/3iu7Rz596xw@cT72vn353GRMtks0sW1CL@jDbSCw9VmhmLHqZV2OVFhtXg5962QyfekrusFgkIESKztHPxeOvRULo06LrPih@WhSCZLoMmBTn11cE@OIUmotZLIqLuQX3gWs63/mx7CqaW/kXfSgfXPklLMyikrfpaZ0z7BAovqf724VcOYmLT1dKj1fKj2kldBpeF4bhBebbQnxxEl6TKhFjOUtTz6ffM9yQIcS36zhYp4/X1E4JayJ3T2J9SUmLUD3MuZ5cwlZUxheeoPxEZXaXiisubpInwOEjFvyeIpYzedkXlJgOWtznYP6M@@eoJ4gh1yZvhwhHwspAbER4C7UAyCb4yk0c6prhssz3nHy1Bd@tDIS6t7hozRa9fq@glTXXX16HEo1bM92npaelyTE6NUQzI3RJK1PL91R548cn//Hf935bHC1urBQ/DOl3tPjb4trTRXmkB3p7ZN4uFzcWnyPb2rfFcZHWwPT45D/@J5Xf@AvBQcr4Of3ZWDWw1saLG4UqF/m6uLFGD@WVFar3f/3rv1IblmTFhlisS01PMWLrhiJbQY95l9JVA62UZelyKlb4YhZgiIUhrc3pBYZR1ytPS7xNt6itKi5D7fnK2KPoKZ4Ns0ZsKiQ7GcaegjQjKVBFBQUBaUwoOsqy3TBmG2DeFE31y31/LaYVwC/anCOpMjHduB/DZGhJlkXUgY7USOt5edgo/ZhPzDsqeWNTsm5USCzttKx9@mid2OFtPxxFrayVhBmu563gKjzxwYd@2L6gNVUv7vZ/HRYviSXPyytPix1s7hfZjrs4YEiFwdj/nRRBHQyIFoZsdOqpIfVA/xwuvDyOFkQK/U5yJmXiSZKWPQhbsoeVjUlMWeSOnyfHw2iOn6rSDv8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qceldzbr6j8wySj5OM1rwts3rJxrHaBURBr2AHLJj/HbcDuoGmPXxue8iUkLgWv65LFD9rtZqDTnNxC3oRK83ILZ2F3UM13xL07fKfixETTX9TMG6EUIuwgFAos6ADrPBwFtESv5vkL1uNpDXCTos9aE1dxKVk7Oq9e1berHHVlTtVXUvUV9Si0hLSehGcsb2zKziaypYqtymHYxJHazIqpttgEbR76/AMMYumWRgfXEnRz@AYkUS1tjrYqs7vN47Uw8chVKHf2ZGtRIlfnFtPLj57JITeooTuhXl8qIwEBL7gVWCjT@4HcgKiaMKNRLyf@/CaSjX8PDYbbsAdXorbbOnE@KtNS7xKxb6IR36VURALtV9a2wc7J7JGATlxsJSFo89h4ybtgqU6FF1uc0XRHhcNAG5dQ@bzsUx21VBJetqOj10qgCPqQL5VXHj1eXXvy9BminC3o1s4Gg0I@VgGDs4BgsEbt0CIb36vV/HJePiEE9XSVgD4LLA7gYNZ15brG7fOVe69aLmlgpTzDuuIwGlJcb1cyyBTiMPQxI9AaxRnmHefHyhEadvyp7X6l/4m/jX9AZjjjjjYQ0lv98Db1TJU7F4cDVRbM7BTHeQQPKq5OsfOG/c4@vE2EsHUVtqeKXsMDxOhs2L84PbO5w9eurQ5pwBDB2S81VlAvw1HqYMzCCrqo3nBoWLcvqgbe0XQLYJSLKQE6nwCnYab9Vgba0hSjY5kmIXjWxI1VHCFapqM2OzN39vqqvrs9idiiHYaO4fq2ZSspd@zJDA5kEKvXau4hUVd7u@CrpFomeRmvyizgSshX5uvwAe5KtxCI2qKKkdWsN4yceWQpMy@mrk3TotSPwGsGzHLpdlKae62mFSCIEYR6NykRYl5ynmOTLMXJ7mSMU/ByvmLZiL6J4pgdzOnK8q62KOVMHFVgIXcDQOzblPLSkFIFPcqPdQ68LL2NYI5yKxpbA9oMOVmphjNzcpgJtrqNxQE2oo4bWqD9jd0tT23X6c/Oh20PivJm7Se0OwnxfDO@ZY1vuaIaO6YLbG@xbHMLm6nfcEWJmKWkHcamCEL4diQqYph6Dag3djTtZVAfZcb2ccoVYNdAK@Fmd1QPEjh64T2QBb14T1xx8HUd/laRzatpSZO4VNHDQra45g9siyYLaa0JJCHlHUCsTIJIHLWk3L6QMrxYoLPmHei1i2Hsxs5sns6wrCyoSG3fKRLZszx7I2XmscWKZouVCvpxHl8w387ljZOw09d30RLmuIU37v0x3ijcnTkK/18wR/2fwx2PNHc8qkD2CHckbsP5RieHYe/P4JiTMc/BzXZ0GmF/qGO9ohElzwLAAg8Y4g4pJZZLaNsN4kQ5sxMeTs5HMBJaWcXFgD/U@Me68Y8rkLn8uB3@v9r4wj@48au68asVzDUzel6rdpa79X9Mi1OV0Ml@mNm9UHclm/tHW7qmW7pWwWw6o5v/r7e08H@opU90S59U4DFBDhzEff18bhZNpHaw1Wik5hZ@TjvtchDHfjZXulh7tat5Wjx0uhfxWRXauvrD@D/V@D@FNOInhKHDWURiG5qs5WV5KpflRbPkXQ6FS1bSEmmv8YxutVdPWOl6RE9QIqR5Y2uoFyqkkHuSmJ42@an@mErfZPK5K84i23WwTBycWwtoWRGW3XSIi@arg2SurCXzyjb7QFZbh/uvH/4XIcN58FnfQiPk0bVXYbdrZhJ7CXaYeJ3SjbGaA9gHes2RYRVNTkZ2pG97J@yycLNUY8cWE/Pi7EWCHLXh/I/WUufQN6yo3NgyItr4urxZVcE01ywv5Au1XTLNbrJu8R/i0meaS59V1L5eGNxEqkBv@GleTNdpK6ur8@YAKeXjBwOw5FH@OaPqfwM)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/bdv92)

Use `git clone --recursive`.
Run: `funge -std=sfish polyglot`.

Funge++ reads file in single-byte encoding, so it executes `/1a97*.;` on line 614. But it also  treats \r\n and \r as newlines,
so it jumps to line 59 instead of 64 (there are 5 \r on line 21).

The code is inside Puzzlang: `583nnn;`.

Answer (score 1):

## 386. ><> ([suppen.no](https://suppen.no/fishlanguage)), 16625 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?4|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0+---<?MLot ~<p>3:s4oya 8:n?\let d=    5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6yfX@uC/SmXogA5kh8QwjSq/NyZJj0Gaibqjc3bBl2yFXftobiEX0SwFe2tf1xLUj8DPpnhx8ziGRsAFmcvnbWdED9qhPO7GJ@mQ36TA9hL24YBv@AXbwEIMj8f6RfVQ7adpTA8/c8y/qTGqbkEytpubLbAc/VlVhaobSxO/vlbl2vyCxBts894@jVyrqJduoMbEiMl8hQKismyucBsCoKhcKxaQTlW1OwGczOMzO6Nsp7ILRHBwI/Wo@AzZZiar1qPrH/SFPm@dPD58ePD/eO37xvJFpXfrqAIJS2DakFigduZPtiVB4H2/A23P186SGwoLk6LsuOHfnBeVi@K2o5aLVloq2KJS4g3E2z21bUUgjgiJdQv4kkadGvjhCgROHHZSYKshXhlHhyglIxwLUEQctUppQaRWWWZXwWAc@ddP2/a9@Wo188dN7Ffz4HibsawyHFj5wnJ6fomew268gxQd7h49ePDtgQQYXrebM7E2GtXKeK5TnWlqgnvombRGtsbgfJQ51VavFH8QBMXE5ziqkw4KUuUNDh2ABdlD7hR97iyU2CT5gMB5WivKfv6FcxmU87ZCEsPEgU3FIFto8NZSNjQ12DI2E3X92@MnBM4b5P7hPzogiBMGO8QD9n/24xz@HEii4Cj476I6IqSQFQUJUiUagWWKh/AJxTn13vP7jg/T5EVIxEX73JPxwkyDQZ3Gg3Z6RbsoreguTpEqMfyzRVysZJERNKPiEAi6soYpI12OnpmeiggvMQx81Ni43dtyLR1pKZbaHX1bE7zfq9G0eyPrUnnCtaL5upBi0NDmkOWm2SZnlX/IRIwHj2xvQ2DsGyBvMs02geJMKew0tERevKlwBiiTV49eiBKArZJKQR40EvKbi0VOarvL@1/6JMqgyME/A/B3fPMvcA9uv@LY@mH@Vm18q2NCuq4Rc5CWaIVTj6peAZyTEP@I@8kFJmyudWSAONVcGhJWZI6imU8I6Bucp8KcE9HgBJ9H4BCoNmhvUmK9shqdnuK0E6pGtKAo2KZSBZTrqY8z4vtsr@mQL@UJOVSCT0mkAkD4AMUCFAhxgMlmBbiKcmuPaK5Crtre3mYgTYUatUOU1q2zaL7PiqzCjmxBWOBti5hoM4kCURQzwq/vRYPRJqUmMitQrrsaRcPUcGJbIH4cvtNs@IkSWAGRxHBn4RYEZfnt0Auyhrxe5g1/rjHwcaNMHJKkwJpEpKQq@mpYnzgSaD3TSxee/uJoW3HfOh0BUOOrxL/KSOmJsj/L1nrXQLhB8hcjvazLSAA4qm7k6mkbrVvwUQTxHEBVxVfNtvGTNSdNuKbxtMmimP1zRmG0w/7IyWNNmebn3riujTVxVJYvIYrvPbQdn/B5AYVhCU7SsohaSiyLlciuL5JfITwaKgxqvLiA5IFNAMrqG@doZe3v7B4cfHz19fk3hKoWMXw0GdL@@nWpKcrrRCg3xaLGWq@TeA@X543sPgopYZLoQocZA@P2SqDeVZDGRjyAXB8OuFm1VDq@Wbn2OP@WqI67mN6vdlDWKdC0fauZLpEuHM6QHdMTyauJaaRW28vmbsrSAp0RA7/Pz8deymkieXzZawG7bsfj1lrCiI7yMyVvYCcDU9LY2FWzs1wuHBQu/lX2MXyH0on0xu7oviptZ1OeH6jkmzslC46HvEPGIlDdIBkikICtB0LW974gz6Qu9nBr/ljdXBBhVcxbJcCFzE8YjoI6Dz4IjFVloFfYV6g51b2iZHSFQL8cV6wb6P0Odulw1XCIp@N@m4Qkn/A@FzyozmXZiJpJI7QhWmt2kozeAlxSgQyN393TqDdlTZ8y/VUA7bu4bgemZA@T3/pTP0Bns4@kIwvXp9cyg1U@g3BJEBkzGw6xyXgqohK@id5ZCJciQXgMV9foFl0e9fGKWlIfGrGcOgLYnkmmgaHdUtcVCNb5YaFLba8dFqrNFLdzYFT9CrQdRtH8pXc6zRQb0hi6bds@YJeJn8WSlBemje/zs09N4UlzVlkintK9kuXdVuXSY/aJ6MyXRJ37vDDQ3r6IW5fJ1KgFuVwFzJYfBh9LKZXnoCfThyxpy7s8n7iMwAhuR6I/0MUtMba4gUmZkTTQTdpo050l1rnzWZqkUCVTwIg@ZUcw@mfj4ndDtOUsoNfw2Krh6dg9fb80xa6iy3AIzJZJkm/gBw33guFBlalIAIRiiVAhsDZsQiBmQI95JZN7AIQ76Q1h4kZrNFd70PTdaJHIQJ1RqVr/LIh@kXOYcxXK54lfoMlUsM2h918mhrADYa3Qu4OsBu77uKMAZiL@yEFsQ8usUL0bpxnhGHvpKpyA7sYjC6EAXFQNYC3XO3aGLd@LAhr4C/EGl8uL4QbuUVEQWKq8auGYPFzH5Nw9CEc//ShV0U2UpaLzKJbqPMBqqCW1z7ViorfIBdRjxCkmNRdHgq1oOhGVv0TZV9cZW70f0awFC5nAA8A/5tgNwqNo1mN1c4bea2P/sZzFkNhKbqnrSdk9T8XymCg@1mmd5dmezKUmbjUxtd1MHKWryZtYEmVzZyt0/NYb93uFAaYoiy7Kcomydn5/HH2w9NV/mWUHqmVrhzWx@mS1k38wus2rpzclYLTTkN7OWWKqlT1rs6dPP3rXfJcXZ6fyN2Exosf2jC1HNocgfq5TZ@U4hGzspg/gJ6TJ2wt7CddJn@Cfz217ErKO50wcRNi6yWLMJGFfFoqgojXgL/iTuv4KLC/6NulyXd1rv3iUbuj6ZzZlpmmOv14PbGQIHqSWfM5CX7wKl5xEU1qQ3SVB4jWb96/MJecZme8ZgMD3Q6xqe/5Z329W5OX0wefz5p8H1Aq@3zyLR3vpfTE6lEpLUWDFPUWnr@Rh@e/nPfrJxmT5/2t7@s2@OFGMDX0f4@s7lYzQ/V/N3Njbu3LuXy6U1TePmp58//cW9vb3c/XT@aSO/k5MyG9t/@icbG5q2rSkbLc9TW/HGyclnopbJifKf/Sjefvr0655Xz/6f33hXV/FRhMcpKwKdgCvLVDDiswS3ijzWh16xtzFo5WpsTr92LHA/32Bqfaf4X7539CY2idU15VMX3pPYm1ihFONGMIAtG9hOY/XYNgYrXMbmSq1WA2Pxv/xbiF//GOCgz3wbHvV8AKswj9WlGkW5iNULYFA1DdL9v7/xjUgOOZmoERsXXLusAZeYK2riTguuLbq2BVQKKmUUJQhnT4YTw2Fq6a56Fy0mWOBlG/h1BWPSjOHX59nRLmPPGqlUqiW3JbjklzRJpKiq1lTVu0AOpDtbtZq0xbja02w2fxdVtydpSmvgwIhp3P30H@KKrXKs/tzgngmxwsbuq/v1OpQpW89u1VN0@R2J@lSxJDrOrsjS7FUcRJBG69UjxnU118VMSRPT6fRum@wzxJU0C1sSXvwZi4Uu2GXZVbelKBDEd419@XCxA7z@/H/78@//@ffo9326/wNqTbV7Zl/ZgkCn0CXqcO1WKt16Xay74nkT7XVoR5lKqVJS2pfNxBZQoNYzpmY@uojns/Hn/MvwKmPNJMWGi5Kt@8mjvR5bONe5Sz3q5nvwwOTA/FKQYQlrZA6xdi0cDK3@/nKpcVpvScgQ1aSGWsi3JB6rHlxl1tiFahK1Ylls1bW8dsR22zN@seGmx5wYSIaFAI9@fuuLstVDn4WtHnWK1YNo9UWYLxsuzK8QazSUlkEDQuDGdjcqG6VKoaIp7fr6C5pm1EpBDcN46sVOY@HFMRtbIDQWNs2rbkFVhBYWtGD2ZcJBZX3IZDfVUragilXfpLWZWIVGomUlbdAWM6oY9jac34drA370hyu04nODXHxnCnL92mAVdUvLKvk7hQMNx9dbrmheBRgnWLfT6bztdoDr0PWO3tXViT7VZ/pcn3SmnVln0p12GXaZ5Rn9rJN3Ss6MzegvS7FsXt2M3aVG/a6xwZ5xKtRiqeBqpm69Xshy2zeSwcFbkpxZTIj9A1x1VVPZFoxPGXgAU0ZGkJnxp6oCiwGjdd56t9V4twUdtJ7aJuLYqkt@LuElt3dbKenysgHmatX/b9dDY5UuboLCtS5Tqe2XdeA@XtYbKQD50gcpS4yAyu16a5t8wsT81Hzv7RbwL1Jqu7Fdc/bplqmDSC2AuL2Uy93dlAymXYhZ3wQBNrUpSRs4JDb8IQKCtuqpoDCYdAKYhPPzD7njOSdecHZXeIGYB334cvuyftnYvrzc3ob/Nj0v/Te4Xm5f@9Nrca0Js/BvIWFpNpR6U2n6pKIFdlmpo4usNMFQhzeEa2S1UquBBrjk1n@bfzm9eIYumOWWDLkWYltsK4YaPLOxLSH26v0X/wvezfdf/D5yiwx@RkWInWOnVrZQ1ixzkRMezH5ss8f8ssGMd2BFF3R4XEdHmz9sXI5SlFcyq/AZ/4RaKiRlHH7bTr@NSkFk9gqCXqN8TNRKBbGdUucai22LhSIRu1@4dsXj8X/0SisX43yaBrVavPI873Ekl4t8QuCqllEl9aLOP9zAv7HzC6uuf/QL6y4hdlFmRgXwk2AcMUIM2lFMUSQJhqv69giPPeBCiYQy6WntM@nFnoSTKPqElsG6fIKgdnhQK5frfI1n8yl1nq37W/BU4X@wAcVgzT6EbfZr3RGwv81@Nq81Uct/TOq8wd@jt/hjx138PXuDP3b8Fn/PJvhjjzv4O36Dv70O/o5H@Lv3Bn@P3@LvxQB/za9ks2pV3DwnzKTUsnq5ORMJQ9XYTr35lYk7r1iG3TB7Lf8DVtlcmSVjza8Ys64xnlS4Yz/@0@9@85vxWi0uxemzQDnVcZmajDEMiN82ZSxZhZpQMyqU0ItXd@NfaZCIni@3GhikBb5CrMY21U01Y2W6GbWjdsBgsozLMsPMUO2pJMpkDJaZZ@YsM3LUHpgM@GXAZGb6LDNgGTtjQzDwBdOknZmgqQ@vAfz6AMiFn4kbfTtqpssgIQuZOvroqNrGmJmLdlNosDgTXxkgi8qqnJELZgs/1dQQX71qKlstrVxiMjY7ud141Yy3xKaI6vu1co515sZG85UIQ3dG5M0TXVjM80DArcaUZlPhmAQkEaIvL9vtgyf3220Fh6nmY@do8T86GkWtN/5HR87jI2fkwP/o6Ag6l1FP7aaAju/u1oCu@6@dWL2606zQsBAMDTFle6dZz0poLqSA6GvolvqS1wIivOsbTSF@BgLGGcgm1QRIKGfV02r1jAyfcisY2mhGx/B/5hv8N0GohvLNGVynBJZsaDz7tBmauEH59AycPmUgl4V/EACj1v8Kf/O/rf/jFyzJEo1WMnF@uZ2gK4m/ZPL88vzSf9aTiYRvSWzDDx3AjlHOL@topEDnYGokkq3k5SV3g2ciuc0B1iGZ7TrFXYSDgSMWJknJ8kfiv@4bkvavZrwKfDGXvfMZ6kcxscr0xb6bZnOWySSrneDLJLiKrF/Q5oZklT5LudlpqK0//RF9fWYnSYHyuWpV3WLcouW0ajUX2IqlarUUWDYTifL1q57ZUQsgn@RyyWS1CpadAGwGrBC3wd6lWI014dm6e5cnUtIuLgKY2VwhlcH9TtVqkFIekjU8vevT5PPDI/pwC5CafAy/mMRJSSJDn33CTwvGxYp4926iZ@Bu8t7OXvLuXa2cubgIXcZjcFKXnNrtnum22@ievbgQ2yLtkynnwZ4pXVyomXJKjScdN/EEv0kJSSUkld3R6pRqGSi9liuCt5@B/PZ2IVevF3LgUijFk7jmzkk85Dcuxqti7JzKoJaKnAKKVXSO7h@CvozjBDu/jFGFslw@mQBCmgQu8TKGPxdpLh@R8vkkYOZS5CHVcpkHTbJcIVFKlf1fbQOkdmCD@A95uWwqt1Xc2gWeGH/ebNWFNLl6btTUy9q5UcFZ98tq1/@6Nyo/Me7ezZYBRaVMtSm02/f3jvfa7RqMZchKwQMdiboLqBPGjVequ1SvainPoAK5oxSHIYGVAMuKtpVXS4gVweyjMiPAgcDFpw22IWj0xodQ5qjaAEeQbyC1HlysxzpsgBcboDTHTGbRxSzG/enZ7YaBHH75vqGV4pLAF7gY4SX43S7L2ySM2k8f7e0fHKe1bYnFtAd7@2nt@Yt7MRWt@YWdvLNof3awd//oBUR4@uhg7/nBR4efHLx4Cu4eO1tcAZX3n4t31LTCfsY@FV67b3XD0I2pYbTPptOzN@y1abZNqD1rCoVyBi7zjDaUZawvylWFu2t6@uvXujumi73/4bff//C/e/87333/O99@/zvf/@kX3/823D@G@7v8/d1/U87j86df/LPfff/bvwOO/wHuP4L7Jz/94je@wW@y/zHc/yni9sf@HQnHbwFg/cpPv/jej376xa/@AO5/6d8/uH7/2k9W39//1vob433vd28O891/C/fvcVhB2O/@NnfD97Xwv83D/eoP3v@Lf8f/f@r/0Pg77//FH@PDt/zTH/zpf3r/zX@vaaU//dfvv/W999/65vtvfef9t/6x9v43/rWaiT5@9/33/@Cv/vD3/uoP/0f6/5iev/ch//c/@Kd/8b/@xf/@F3/o3z@B@9@B6Sd/8e@hq/ztH/wQ/9/7g7/9ox/i/3/@V3/7B7/@t7/yP5HhN7nh//mX/4Y///rX/uPf/NZ3/uon3/ibX//J3/zmH/zV//Gr/9dv/Me//u9//6//yTfR8Td/8ld/9Ct/@c1v/@W3/vlffvOLNc9v3/j84gPcv/gHcPnwfH4InA8p15d1@eLnys/fBxuLVKCdQOv@5fe/8UvQwP8FY@@//WM8Jwj3mv@PNZXC/Jjb/j9g0K6XGX0yYIL7199/@7uIov8BUAT/EF/fCS1LPtzynYUF0PpbKyL98k@/@Oc/IlvMqNRpGQcH65JWSm2BQLNVLvsDtr/CA1F@aRlaCMBP6TtIoZb8voO07f0Pv/H@R//4/Q9/8/0PfwVHaylXTu@lJfWW5TEImP@AcBiw8CHhMOBnkH47RVNvUuozsG18li9lbduufvbZZ0L7QsEDqbsX7DP4sc@Ci3EvPLDqewV@6I4nWBm4N169auGaasRNUTlwReNv3wu3vENKknYntaOoGvcyLpRNHotVwSFbyjYjWVf6/a0K/Bg8KpWt87S00wSmj6JeCkZQJNWHuqEwVU9nt7I6BFRyPByr2LuZXKq4pesgAqcQbop4nq2AB8tn2SzlJzljfH0J3SHQbIuMM3ySK3rPBHws/gvjTGApmnTmSx@phZEMfjw/CW4U8pBMahauahFTyDhXtsVdaMGa0s2VGZZgNkvNQNoGA6SQAq97wPfXaimMWOP5ASvPWr3EKCupVA3KjbF5nHS7hCBm9wgKxKylnrH2Vm3GI6YQXj1AR0pAp2eiqompUu0@JFib3WcIC4ET2FevavVSbVZHcO84PlKz1D3KEwKrpWb1d2CvEUyIJ8Tuv4OslGqpVL2ECWIhefWk27yS8lQ4KnuKpfw6gDeeO9jZZeyOqJZEvlqxgQjjofGZWoTGgBAc/JupLb849A@MdG8RwjcoKT8Vxv13iCfe4WwyBgC4kiTLMoMbNwLssF3wnnFQKUoWXikOIUUtglpA6MBwIiolpKh@U2SB9GO1rS99ITAszObmphCri1nxSCbUKQpzTyp0CAP3JaIcU2FioSyis0EnUoK8QPwqpb8ZxxW@OOOA2Z0Uv3d3t9gdKCa9F24Ck1JZJ@fEOJTtVErUAH7dSQkvQf4RoJ0SoAtBntVoRTElpNOMybUY@rGjoyM/E@TwsiakoJlrWRXtuK41nU5jEEOW03I67b9lepOD7Btk8vXf8iYil74OzzQtVwUxrcrQiUVlKhVkbXR89@4d1Apt9KocgpTL/D1fWq5EnuDA9QFZ1jw4uqTlygKfAmBqIcdYgmZ74UoyPKOTgIaUFPgBAZ6N4ErEtVIpTiEB/3JiK9gEWFCpQeBkb6yOWQ0uLn2W8snAc/@I7R89fnzw5HjcajHBoO/dG@2x63QNz0ug396T@/xwiFYuJGONBoI@rmhIYoSDSgYTSh3ef3b4vMJ4sf1KSFDGqrTE6xe0rAqx8fjT7Zi/CUrETzY64nN8VhZlS2jlLESN1YVY10CZBtfuUdausqrw2Bvcc2YskUmLYlotoEyZxJVKyMcvOlOGCoW59iHoVXhkRN7eJgwI9XOJ1lHQCPVVEOp1f/sgU4X684NjiHB8xFQtIwv1z9hMxgSlS6Fu1SzDHkyGm7gPT2xmxEiZNhuZNP60bBaeaq6QVvPF1saGdS5hmk2qtnPcUHkJ1nMJi/FVuJjwVYF9FZzggjRwlyTzt6geHlX9fYKoui/BNwuKah46WlLAWXUOThhHryq07@VVKSG28fnnE1avgygvHT4QYkAvhizYKieZPXkoUzX3pq5BvgPGeuYnJn6LU@6Z3tjS59B5ABuxy8vLPkA6fMC0ukZWHqOHz8suuXTAfDnThZhdqdTeqbmioJ1UKu@ymiaAg7Cl4F68DWgAtKVhS@G/qgeJZLMlBWiVKorwymazAk5TC0LFEBhtW3mXqdUk3gazOZV2rQj4eRd9VtPCyw87u7MIm83wsOgDHmwwcVkm8CtyP99WEMgGSMONevQx8arfPTN372ZxviSby4QTI1Ridgl1s5nNZRHjeBCqFcsV/RUbURRbMcEyJqxXA3OsCQ8@96epMZGhDclGtpQRYo1YQ/j/@@UvSm2P69mMuq2MwaiDMbet6GDsgDG/rXTAaIKxvK2YYJzWs2pmW5nWBSZsc62/DJUK1cSJMUMl49xNrHuG1ZfxfFRNpAQ0cdvXol8PItZ7tZ7TneLWlGpPNm3bcFEFAI@Qy4lVx0Z9lDXUTENKE1gieS4MamekqEAwagMZVRy5tm4JPbnj9OayN5lbeNLIctxaHDjVeOCxgG4AC4PzczvZbK7SYC157Ix3BC1fTDXUDIw9eKultJbeMHaKxUpP7lqG7u7kK/lSuoeHmPyVup18pjKQP3v86OFkMn5m0MmmnVwZIqBSQFTftVOq5POtRkMUUw1KpoUfQOd0TdrYAGJg6D0J3riO50laqQWRe6Zbq8XjO1lVk9RKNlO6FBaIQ5xjCesCRk1hydKI93OfdFRsxwYqVUnrafOcsFDp9/uXW@ephUXQzyVuA/xcSnq6cx5aq1IkXIVN05K58AQXvQ/oPveXKCuili@J1UZ1YS8WxGrrUtgdGT1TxwNNzcz59VgFoOYcagwSajLhsuI6zqTSMfqOaywCZtVCEJBn6HqAnHgZJtfMYIrn15MrRALNzq9DyeXFyzBWkC3h8hLwzpENaPdVOtdp429DLedaB0C7oPlsB9qeMVjs5UshtvXsk2y9DlV9nitquXwur2ULhXxRg4GqnCuAvJZRM4VMXtMASq5cKhcvoV0ryrsYfcyR7Z8H7b1Cn7NI6BWuj7XRYsl3T0zrvJSVeD4SyerlZeydELvz7BMNRta1VwJG6080qV7L5stgyqJJy0KGmaBpkpaVsqqkZvF/i0HD/4eH1@Cv4RNiZTXhGJU0PYHxFngEmz1CZS8Thx07@LmvAbtndNeE2B/qtCt733U87@8R5p5un3Cv@ybXjBx6PdTxm4feyJwM14R4MR6hfifD/QeDcDDqQAaRHPIA9@DhWo6zKkCRvXi6ppSPw28RADL4xwgg@LPDjx4eR97HB3v7D4UCu3f05P6VV94PlGePDh4ch9Yi9w2i5kMQv3jw6NFVq//KHb141p86Lt7Cg6MXucUjdMJDv0IOruVAoTMB8R9oJY4UWBGQ4fLFwKAKeFTkLsjVd31jvrAwZtD4KT/RbHrh0QV@uL0iHAfHnHWGlLZjsC5X44WCPqnY9IUAtVgWhDGznTNWzLCeY1m6y5x@fwMchzoe2TSQE7YsbImY9JnjWr0zs2dsCI/xdGhZheCUCeEhABlNu6QhArggVNgMo5rNcOmsY00NNh2ztY7wQic0uuZgCGPwmRMEEDq6zuD@shfEN6LX5GaHCU@D3K75WNeDCzFhN1bKi@K@KD7UJ3rVNYovq16mUlHj8aeuWBbHMCrr3sA4mEHDZS@gI@nuPC1OZPEBk9uxAa7HWM4Y5Rdv3ACGv6w1Wju5i3opk8/@9W/9@O/@5NcHNZpCamb2MzintL3z@JEzYe@Qoah4OWeus1LF3mlyHpE2@VeABgKfzIgV9tllmQQnrVzKl8pZrZQulUu5vFrI59Oqlgaps1gGsSOjltRCKV9W06VcGdiVXBl88@Wiz2wrAXetbFUArN3Fr7xvk@wlD0HI4muq7G1CT7KYHtqnTDQgjiigoDuhc/JbZg1GWqZmWLbIAKLOuiz24MF@5sEDUbyHFtyTsp8RxR5a8qVMpnhPFA3y2S8h6yU6PE4J9WWKE27JZO5BVUw5APzUhCgO0XJQwKlCUTTRsr/34AGm00eLhvEh2An34RYrsBQhmI0WkAEIwJsQGgTb4@nkKKMHaMEk0ecB99kHP1H8KMgO@jzjwTiAh0FJ9/ZE8ZBb9vbQZ5@KnecZ/Rpa9ugSRRcs0EdEcQCGgQu9UxQ7YMSeIopdMHXnOriNwIRfI7AnuijOOXoQQaI4o9B690QU24E7JvOJn5s8YrdCFpWXepcsZfyJohZkGoNlQ0tWFHOhJQdle/jwE3046RkDfs1d/u5CSR8@zOrmbHrwoPPRR53BoOPO9w4@eoZe@/sPgW2ZT93OoONH7LThciDW/kNNPxnNr15Q6sN2u6JbK72@1m7ndPuKV3veNjCHEOsN5My/BpjQqL0PXvsP27v6qjVxAthGIjGCdweveyN439M73Cu4yIves05HrGLzV5RmQkDBAhe3sTueANG10yO96zpVtM9qLJPGHjxvFDKtKnmwEQgImeol@vcT@NRxfil5Pm/MaplWbVYranxTVT8hNmda3hTTG6MdtZyvbOg7qpZLzSqoqsPpx1lcUndYQr279ZYlniR3NBAWxObOjiQ21NaOppYqheLLrakoJiv43MkWK28TmXiGMXwkG8XWTjEfiVEspnRFqxSLwLIBTiYw8ndw0qedSJwZ@kkyibmlKQgoApWVzamcZrWfmKVnNZ4vNk9WZzW1yrVws8w1YD385MO0O3FcDnIA4GY7mQpupEiIarkkQgYUJZFMhkRPAdNix@unXz8@OT7@jHjDuj878tQ1kHpVfetHD/flw6PAhh9rkB8gy@q48j5SrSUfzrsGTscgrMgPYbQFwS9wwyORrmPJB7RTEPjewCPQFyX7ipPl44dLcJ4PnTOeMmqUqJL2TbtrMPyWhdljeq0OJr3HEpQrpifPaJxv1@u1dm1EShegiEGsrzH60MMCzKHH8x7quaDo53hM0Pdo1zKX1U5tFpsBnHaNSeqrkdN7paW61R5@wuJe7R5Grrbh3akaNcN1HVcEsVus9nfs2tT29L7x1HBRg8vh0SZwHXh2MNFnRnKTNQ8w9D6KNJdS3WX2ImdPpqOELtU7yWUnnPkLHRA5ia8HhT6n46ztmiheVvs1lngJQd@A3d1kiZ58L7mTqwKe7rF2Epwyr/qv@kxjhVyVRJIEwoKuRPjBcussWat/DV4c9kmlArnxK/oEoGJiANjskQeEHpuX1W7NYgmJzViSkJSrDmoNjH6Bj21JFFuS1LhoCXVJ@lSoQ3@tzmN6zZt26OtHLNNRtUyhOgM3tZirDqF69ZezqlsbT12jaoHVnzDkJ3f1KiAVcAdg3l4k3v/SN5LbUr7G3aoE6gKZgLbcrs2qNupThYZRy9bAI9XIZdIg7MOjmIYxXyuk1UI6m86lpSK6woCfzqfBEYQhYEISVkJkTExnZhlZTauGmk5kXpm9V8n0SQKYG0IaS6YnzoE9HTFwgarCtklWeAN6UtqWBUJaz2H6tkSNFUhGFQsGWB@ysZkeIqhnhm5RjGRSYtmthLWZwDCbx9PxQaNVqRzMxl8Hr4T0ZqeQKmZSb5PJamIjWfOMN0K9KtSRvFCpxxvQcv25VOZNRw2oZTCpRa3SaHSwiMVMOpvJQunM9sVgW6yLrXRmo6BCFV0yIhuM043o9CJyPAu3cRuZdMuAqlPLWlWQaa4vW9KkspLfymf4fCOPKYx98oaYZImmGJxST8TjRS0eT8aruNaxIfpT20DTiJ7FgbrG76o7IjBjYkUsaxhgQRrpIHImyB2wY5cCco4sBzLwuXB5frldF74iPMfjpdvaS/wVXz7eO8LfV8CpDNbSy8cvjl4cPRCYQvtWgQ2tblTlarsKFkmu7wqxCmNASZu@Ci1lg7EvuyM2tV1/yd9NPDMBcAXSkd5gLdqpZpgo4LFPUD3DDotDGXR31NC0bKuhFWHsA2oaBNU0tYpKqWJ4JkOuK3T4LlfM0uE7ITY7h8xup8j9a2w@11NSMEVwl@0OUpv8MFFZ3MZ4BT8eX5jbxEin7dMYw333L6un1ZNMeVsg5MaubNCv7tX2Bs/2qkzMFotidW@/DUYxwWJVMe8DreYexp/Fj@OH8e1kXSwVyLW8i1Pqq@cw6sBdnZyo/oGnYqYtVmOsLeb9k4WRU1E5cbvcFHA/fzx2Hmex@CX8Fll8@TY4NFUAGCeZ7ZdAD2NhdpKxIAmtLb5kXvVEUjPb0GR26eSoxk@Oslh4dhQXzf2lpGyuwJLlYJ3nK/HdWByXUyqe925xKNGHrrbFeoyBtHJSjW0zsRTg5W3mpCoWC76tLOb8Aib9JEAExRYdnOn72isNOlPMdgIHEDtxShAG@3weVy9iyqux97lWyj4@PLLvuw8ip8teYgYgB3hUrlp52d44UaETZcXsSTrGdmN0wEIsQ/oadwCEnzC1@hIRz8QX948eizlEFkhw4JSAQvFcQ6LNjYsNB5erWLhf85398dcZG8ezOdzvWIvNajn/rIBar0vqtoaa/IqsAkNmXy1ImYs6Jwp18iho4PP@l36Qm22XwK5lVLBrWj6l1evqlsaSsfH7L34fdTKdH3yy94jFcZHj7/7kR1rx7/7kX9EOxPglLXxo2WIMQqJRLRRj5@fj8/NLuLhfPtaKXdt40YLKVFS9XNySoTRKSQdDW4nxCgEmsagmY54U87eZFvJSIqEqWnIrW8okwefC17mW0DIlsAZrf@QkFvJiMnbwzMxr6u72DpRsJ5vTqhvQ0tTwjDILf9uGV44JsdLjVxeMgaVb7w0GpkYmRWGVdxLbfidts3e47PZO2mCvanXcOKLiyeZgWWoLT3ri4my8nlK24gyES1ZvXFYvWyla1wJp/aVhbNnNK3hobuBhn2WnLRt@xpZHP4wUOHhgDWzG1mtPTGwlFaXXE6/37G2D5evQVLaUxflrthWsVvGfJDWT73/pNzSt8Hd/8msX7Yv2ZxoI6OVyQdViP/vZ9tSeekav/jMAcIMmnkDIJj4bVeagIRTOGddPa/qxQoPcFYXY1EZBhIcPRHUUzhkwcebANnokqgunyHhSzba5MshegoJtoaKONAkypHwtWRWEgOPngoo76KYJBttCpcqNVlI4F76KXsDXMBB2qsJXF6DAYQScjNNte9bUHdNhqQTFU1tpdheiQApfRUWbG6RgxB8UJbXKlK3rUXmWPcIaMalsZHgequ2E8Vz4KkTxNc9bczbWURcOhjRtGIVlDEL5JI9eA9JuQdoWj9Am1wSVngdIM547HskGYUb4KvBlhAUT2DVmbkOAKlCurwICoAwJH7DZYtssm2TnZipVXegEvcRDG6gNVQ/0cAgYDaH1UO9LELmK4cAJhCj81jG2C7@GgVuOOAZAOAy@9aIGYhhGJxtywKQo54NBASxSSpegorG7dxe5qtXMXpJRiRD@iTnG2UaqB3t1XgFYIMLe6VXENENtq9XANWx2gPEUZRdancTVrFYjUZmI1ktBgP8HN1pskVeqijyqWAC/vniv6ALKIDKinddhl23XmKoVkyzMfBfy3qVMkTaEUC5vzu7I2meB5yXk8Gex4EtiQLSOozO4fru9qoiFgdQyxc84oTo@Tgx8BSpc4R4Sv8NJEDuMBUUxLQrdN12QGGlPSKDrM5FVkxhtoRuV8kHHKrQcw9MN@SS@KBaGZvDWUWeln84G6drqOlCh3tixScklKeHCoyXQIoBG@foBeban9hl@9s@vG4oczZFHugGx5WOOSWmng9qMKC5uyei4hn4S4CbNjIHMuqMe08osQQ2N9BjaIbgkRaIMd0DwQBx3LGMEWXpuGHRk0asoygCY0WmHlDk@NqFdDR@YMALZnnKfI1g5M09M5Rj1b0tOH082ctU4MeRfsfvx3R@@4kTLcU6YZZ4YfGI@saRYyGMgeoH0kAbMLm5AbAU3FmnZNM4AqWkeCu4ivIrcWEpH4m4k5snr76y6kWhjjV7QeGNCrVjGqW5H8EvXheDPOXhzL1BNRgq2wC6HJNfwlRLV4qhuJNS2JfhK1mqk30vGBZ9xQoyJgXIyNApj1zhlOHsg4BgDRLMbqPnBXgyl/SoNANT3oGehztKJW0HlVJATt5foQtfzCbzN7rCsJmBArjnO1/IGMLDqa8vQwQ@iYjm8SQ8qRqZVDqQr0DtHPfBDtSh@88P4QetGM@mTXTRvtuGDw0GH0qox3i0CSz5iwd6B7ZmKvgGeBcjhipxsJMQUgE2JSZGDDuNfjc5bu0C0pMKuQ0ozhOCjGqAQq6AjyUGllJHv8wngcU/3@EdcfI2mZ2dnMqnZnbqmbHj4zTrPsXVLGQ9MYLodZWKMxv7Xwc2uMg7gLkwS/1SlPB6Od2bI19bKd@f8LQh9r@ZvzkrE@14cB8dT/CTbYEQq@VAXnkcN6oFJn3PsJvy9Yrz9aa30edD@Ktj@pFL8EoGAvAZgZul5upsGYOlO9yTdP@tVfY9T6pAAHGrRCBxR@bUbWEZeYDLH/TCEM0E6Gnp1rBNaNgdIIp8qXyTNSxiEnAdW3z42ZxDJNs7Ynuvq8wT5JzE0NuDEnNgeNodhn3zAiAruz7kmZnPWmLeWos/C6DCohZtGXNS3J5zfDJSr5Ub/Gfefgf@M@88WiQbJNmYtzpKh0yUWB1s9qmkNQiKYeRDmkquwXvgQZODHQZgiNww5X3K7hLtbo9gBvrkN6rEWNAxoE2NAuJFQGi@bjWbL9oyzrVZKGUBjFwkRUOMAutEinJ71QjNi3zq1xo635GSjdl4Ylfx8o1N36LcG3lawjGEFUcPg@DJRoepg5O9u4QyBX2CAgHwYeCJrsDdJmMlqqAeePKHhNMQFjnnGGn5mWsR9@V6@G7BLHPUcsVFArQggdA@LBNkEHxb0HP6F0oA6fOo6ECYIK9FHFUeo2C/eigMmr3QVTmuqVEmRXElSkE1AO7KrtatFCfyhKhpXvCLFvPTrP5r9jS@d/T70i9W5pwbLB4yqEO0quBMVWAi/uxBWWb0WqVfIgbKlW4YLI9cB50/90RqS2VICMYOng0XwzsxJd5iIVH43yeuHjtaKtlgJm8K8VoMizmu8W/J@EaCUIzyM5vnR5kFD8ONzAgIwMiujGX60WTTarFbjhIPN1kQ7i2RyRpmc8Sg89GxNJlt@NJCeDoPhBaunBdwpbpUVAZ7Kh1Fgg8Yi8/RTA/cgvEalo7g846e5oDnUCvw2hCw2trNua2XqjUimI0TrCgBsiNcA9PjHzivCVYKnSqEtpFEclQGN4ja/GXBaAQ2MSHCVK@ZOhI2MZGBg@MUUjQPQd8VUQxBVmmLHX4bfYjpwDG71umNmOaS67JhJX/n9gzi2ELORDhrhPtRMDgkySjIvbF@jbZTniLG9KQg4wNV1zhyWWMFsg7sy9aMqHcvpKCMd9xLhJ5C5qzyeJwP5ARep2O7YmegTJ5ercKHJpGa3Kn0uM5gD28Evp0WU8wOv13MMz45PoFK7zsA2PSPNUG/qieGLHYb/GRIhyif7RscTBH9XGxdjETRvV8jqttumbU7a7QRuFk1Wwi3ztHcUm2c8LqD8C6ZIfCBPPtCjccL5f7v7vvW2cWTPa@spENlpkwlFSU7sJHLkjmzLiaYTO8d2ksk6bjUtUTY7sqQW5T/qJPOdcy72BXbv9xH2Vc47nKt9itn6VQEkKMmy0z27s9/m67ZIAigUCoVCAShUnfwatkbu7TARaUIXO4xan529gU6EP5GaIhnWIv2fUs9Ig1FxP105shd7qNInI4dDr5z1z/unpPVdxD52mXMT4BspbCAUDAaMi6cCLGkrVrwRHiVOywtcXfSn7y6qflpxAjcpv5IFkCGGp4aTNAZlhzOqa95YnRQz9R18P74HNr4H8/HlVfgkzrI0r0ri91X9yEkhUMYUjUe3o4Gmk9xqT6GTQSX5DL1KCtwZxTbb6rWBaY2y1nR2v0P84SVvMb0liL@/if7zO9AUr9@1@wIa9upgTPLmHGavDge7jM1Zs0PZGy5kz3R1CWtv37Euyos4wztQIUiNZcHVgwNuGpiITBQnG8gG8C08D/O4Kb5nm7mqJM7AaXjpqc8rN3fRdrMddoNx2HZ0Ts@Ca1q8Tws2lld3azgEHQu9vqz1HJq73CSVpnEQXTJVbmCZwLt03ZvZSrJECffwTjlj2LiZfkifEs3Y4qvKbjWtA5aXF7Edexlh@3MwHowlxkNXIh1qOSrzj/Qk3IPcThCig8yeZS@t1p0nPvedpEl3mBGSvH62yXDBbiDCMdd0H34fiW5vKXWuVahqejmXjW40u8ejeT1ucYXhSTl2uhtL3sZ0d@Y5i9UEWCrCtr5vCpmCDAOZVsuxIcqXuT3W703JBHzjfbreDbNKc4ZATUqypBtFvNxm/cLNYWXcoF9sOL2nXwA8DUdNYSjTNuxp6eDBilPOg4GltegvpKQTFIuKQnKNhpUrZ54p@5dvSZ2tG@tsTdXZytSZjIBslVamXCtTpe4FdM@8LuiGndEN0hlJWDvTzzyxTf96/WCI3Yovy9FyJfLU8uVyhQTycrhcqTsklJfby5VtfoiXKwf88Hm58hM9pGNr@etyxQwLZBjSKz@8wHctwvHeWq5sOe633Cj4HMamXn@5kvQp5flRXpkiRAq0m7RGHLH1@rqZo2FIExsrlZ4Cx8Qelk@8D@Px/yX6T@KVcSQjJGKP8wFnVg9VOTNpWDOG1EPThomUMWMkV/RsXt/bYQOzJAuqeUhrPLsMgyc1fHE5K4wEMaTyiQb9EoKQm5XZGClrJrsjOrp24lDu5Gz9TD2f9YG2w@lHlPk4rYSD1Onypr@yIKQD74YnCt@E5xQ6pjrGCGey7gy0QNRfluc0Cn2dxUX3vt1DvNedzUTYFkwW6SUGa8l00uH4cA6VDfqDLJNwKm48RHYZ3pSTQQnunSjGUkGPzBuS@bNuGQSDPfjdec2xygG1jAhC4lHpWEZZMi@wLEZSKussTVUGH6FgyRwa4WHrMwcA3NaPnE/EjcdzxU3TkCkrVbLkyopJKuzD3dlFMJLak8VrHU7Qvm/5akpeY6/FAQCrZFKLyNf@d@jvfdHfjUJtiDBRwSzFevZUOq1ez51lJzDvptVOdyASPbXtzlSOkhpSktPqwNLM5/HalIoPkw9R8qXSBPqEtm/IlqwJbqHb5NpCYEFLGF5mP35eoY@fV24m1LRG0r30jdLioyYNRxqeYJo2bT6u0vBZXYwU3t8Out/dwcNsB9udB3jcgOEEyWWUDy96bOWSjm0S2/IFIrVcUSLI@bg06eb0I4l7PrpNjm3pw15zf3tv9/VHmnSfPHni6jl6nOKHUYu91mQeF8hsrZ7MBzOWLSseonThsBvb8fFZfzi696mXn5IlIqxJGQioFsN@eoy7WpZZ8nxi7FI5yWtRVMP6nA6DICOVoOoEmLIjTdcRESQcOQ8CDcSot0Rvj1drLsejajZ7wXnYbPL0ZQKf61kMXWNOxN2/L94rXsRDDvAtwdSucjl2B6K299SHV7VDdfiqrnbebf2kPu69Ux9qu4fwA/H23ebrxpai/@u7B3WVy5jiIfAkFpRE1@2wFSKcsFoplR4rhrzVH4xF7jhbrnw/CM7Vq34rxDHV8zg4f3EmL34vHG1IqTotR8fYw4w40Oh5NIK9BUfGpGUslJs239LE9QpFeU9oTXuONe95vx11Isqbw9p3EIWxudinuhH1IMlbc7fdEyUJQTDZdIiD28IC64qKB5QfZzcEJhD7K5AYOSRqZttXmnDJv@@m4GF9/82BgkuRrb3d7cZhY2/3QO3s7dPr24@N3ZdEz8bB4X5j8x2SOOObve3GTmOrxh8EgZKv4Ovj14t4NBcFH9mZKq3POPn2B9T9yVt21xsavLoK@L5qrJYvepA@UdCNfg/by@u5ixjqC@7I8lGBcpZq@y/f05yvwt9wwmmOgtn@IP8u5sCsSyX1nGujwbJB421dD1ea9gpll88jzscKsZnCdfYB4vCzpwxwNuJpR6HKb8FGBXvf4iqEx7IBTRXdI9gAZQxWqopjqi0ve88Z5AbV1ur24UJWahMjQv2Coi@Mqcl6jimmbWUAFBdIGj3sB5XXkw/E9/RhRVc7GkoG9Sj5IBnUY/kAVbQB2xG1qnNcjPYuIJ7Vmnz49Xyww8fC6knyYTPgVexTjZP0G3dpoJKYlHCc0uXIebLLw9F9g7gVRVwk5vyIKtftysAIJZ4pyUQ5SmTbNsqZJ2HTwVGDNnuTOOFIJW6AnVDQGcXKqbq@OoRxUNiLJGbhaTfoiQlUarrDvKeewktVVV@Hj5JYf3wlZ9BnBkSc0SweSbltrRWGdy1HJTenagy0jSTH2zUmaLchsDmFwB8BQ4AKmZVOi2cqvkIMMP2OZmUn7hNHYt/2b3Z@Yuf2RSvMFNBWW86v0e@/u5rIXmadZOwUGTvqot/DIamVfJTZ6Q9pjLNY5ehokIKts/5gFEkfOtkW8IkTT3OUGxMb1fZLdSNTG@gwWWOv37MqPSEuvqHWE2LKu9TKHC9n54n4SsNmE@fTJCx2d0AnOOlfhtbZmYdDpKsQ2y@kCPNZOTY/xyPGRPTPXCo7/qYQbfdpdWN781Phb794CLkrYkEiXhujQ/xPjIm6aHjwOR8bLA6hd@mRZkIlxhcnKK1t8LS0xCg3wGgdeBbRuu5Fcz1JE3Pj6e@4rjT5nT9@/VqVUgVIJh0mPT5zUunmqSNTpcdljpU2AbFkJyFLst4xXzyGmcjrF7iihF6A06Ue5AjW7ROBCLUIMa07ueiQZNHxoHV3J/BdtcEWFUaRFD8Zdn8Uf3Y2qw833GJqUKIscjpGRHsGctl1LbMUnq@mwG3PB0fy@@7gns7FTqaH74K2PRfad@FWeHgzLJmWLFh3B/u3OWBlcvtDYKnt3s2AZZKchpZwesKc3tJiYk07v8ZfpvqOxx6BwdyLHZQEqFXbRY@PqI1DdkcKuDaYVCE6ONyu7@@rvKxPqCzJPSwZ2loMAvY99Ta1to16LOz8RGlKFsuJ8mS@ZCzazL95g3km8W4QFVoH8TQ9EmGRun3vRNci9fTMwioEW9@zQDSUy2L3xcig@EgD/kZrQEI27TSrgbmZzVyUySeKbSNwTTdPdGPbhp8trGXuRpTl4dgGZNsEBae4WTK7/z6Iflwx9YiCBYdTaHCbNGmab2idcEAVDyij72d7cE63mC6Fkb0o2IuGdjD8KmU17D/PUMxIooSLLmyJda0ca9REP14yag4bJGIaCGDpqRPFopkSjIjnL8/tDnXTSc/JTkGkZCLu7gubK6j48Tc9hTE1knmymijk9lhbYmyODJbH2J3VsNdvznQfttBrk@JhsiqStnOrKvxjqpJZIlOTofnMxphEgry2uvroNtiTrTDFC38Wtswhk/JzdD6g9X0KMh7HvL1PnNvY9Ux6ygBzSCem9WbATBQkVWfGnJJpO09GNn6Ei@wLETIIaoBQxpO1uup6ArfZ0GVGsqFzlqk2WEM4aaiMminqf5tfHQTyrfXd@/76ZLAhE0wHv8Eq/01/GIfprTzLZ471Cb4Gst/C4bDH2eQ@0zmgOHyNae5lO75tJwav0iok8nmb3ZKOvp0kZree2WvgSnh70Uf0cuzurU9u7xXK63ZTdxqv6@oBuxrtZPYi88O8a8mee1FvHgIsg3lfAtMH3@G7H1fof8LBMyCJTHybz2HauLfixhQhrfmIw1xps1AtW8uTvd@JW0EPXla8/P1Y5b0fqCDvwtb3dtxZO@ul9Ux5Qi4e9Bwq5eULfp6L0jds6AJSFoT0Jr5bExZuahhLSVyvOe3DPgoHW@G17J6x5WRQLD8trT3Lcet63sg7P3p27D1oVfOKJt@gdx5fDK/an0/7Z5cd1VWDX0@uW@Pff1Nq9bF6RHWt/CAen8tr1SK72H1Cf5@qZyXmXI3gj3xJHtG0fQkzrNSyStfh6/eUyw@8aK7ghsQEl6oH54YLccVuVD0/Wjuu9qql9fOj3vE6LvmNHlZHD8sPHXz4gWZRkjFyMn80Osacau@6hr1LBa@qHM5WXw1RfDWEvrwJhlH/dW33ZWY3DgoAtsC0rTdvqEvk8gVYs@Huid8Lrxy9TeYpcGwOClJugW8FleEMgPeTsR3Tjggz6hWPtNn4mv@O3dxCyb8YjPqcYlxhgrXU1@hrbsFcYyrxjgJlOYqMw0zcLyA4aR4HB0PydSxW1IWyqGtl3J10LRBHKMniMP8pn8edQiCq73IdHediPwxaZ0CiS2r1Vy6mnj9XeCNWi33exYMpRzDkCxOlYzziAIR@BnzagCpYc4/52keOmo/3Mh7kC@9RjfieDBvI51hTRArMv9UXvt/E5Z8TAYTwC6Jz@XqLU2tepEjK3UHeXICfuezCH8cMuFYpnbKAxgK21FdNgbOlONMI1Woy0feFK5BTaEX/dAsKZX6bakaS35XsTBI@p9ZvMWjJXcpJG/jppsUcq1jBFDOZLVIs3EoN7HTR8uhNSMNqrLbCbpeQFlospOTAI9/v1fU/TOqPj1DncYK8pBem0guZdF/SBak0l08TfJqpYmfKL35J831T@TSbN1VXVbHy4lNPt3xSSdK86/Pyxv6o34zSzBtJVwpXJgnPMwkFK@XnGb0vKfcyZRIGT9KPJF3z94ru@QTLTN4X2frxm9MdFLLxrLY1meBSvxd1f8zpKO86BWyWJ2oqJcU5fqcyg6qq72BqcUIaHPb5edhuVFMoD8tG4vCYyW88f5H3tZLxozOJhtxinBpYM8aIRSWu8yET7povLFI9nHzPAsEwwWjKjNwNU3isC48tsMh1z1QrtyCnBjg1bXKIV3Ev8iv@mMGeRc7kW5yduCCYX0vj5XZzlkAsdO/lZ5MpK01wXUQ@6kbNmUXSuseTEGcLiV1rFzipM5Q72B1sg99L5IQtKIykmKJ7kqIpnWYoG/a9qQuR@C339@KD3MuAdOxBN7xWNSwzAr6FlctccB@F8SiGny12ARRfDAZdnDqywnfFV6h1EIOVVRy3pBCtmd3PNWDZI/k9POkL6VTIV3uAfAUDkTQhvjg9xWUy3IDtX0G0YsclGvm5Wm8sGxo0Zh6tyDXzUMH5BgvgbnRqIyE9J6MHlI4HQSv0c6SjxaT95KSpnUiHveX9dNwbgTs3mtIqudy/XEStz1svcZ77pFx6VLZIdqmPg0v@o8fpBSsikklYgUfG1fLjXM46G27J2XABAD31GhP9e@LN8DLs9cJcjWYMzhiT0hqHw8uw7edy@2FyCAy4YGWcTOIedv9i2JLNHVK6AmJG3BKOPTkOIw7DL@ZnOS5u8VmZl8OhVXraTF19GbVBQHPjpNPH6TAfWMBNgNADhc7DERHlgauyKPHZs8aFdZdzbEQRNeDnxDqbSMjQ64@iFvUM72TlugRKjkHSynrtCUyovlY3wOVgfxYCuB6TUsAgYI6S5uGQ04fm34WD0g0zZ@yB6ZkiSb8@jxUa7uEwIumbEph7hYtZuFMHH75qHKiDvZ3DD7X9uqLnt/t77xvb9W21@ZHPuHFQzk6Q1au91yRdktN0OTXfow/52gGVzHNCrrb7UdX/@na/fnCg9vZV483b1w2CRuD3a7uHjfqBpxq7W6/fbfPpO0FQu3uH6nXjTeOQsh3ueVyrKZZLy6m9HfWmvr/1il5rm43XjcOPXONO43AXleFUv6be1vYPG1vvXtf21dt3@2/3DuoKDcttNw62Xtcab@rbPtVPdar6@/ruoTp4VXv9eqKhex926/uKjQSsVm7WCcvaJi1hURO3c7uxX986RIPSpy0iHiH42lMHb@tbDTzU/1qn5tT2P3oa6EH9X95RJkpU27U3tZfUuJxzC1WoX7be7dfhPgmUOHi3eXDYOHx3WFcv9/a2mdYH9f33ja36wbrKvd47YIK9O6h7ChE3uWqCQdSidHrefHfQYLo1dg9pznj3FvYOLnXyByIMYVmjottMYJhBoLVEpL39j4AKOnAHeOrDqzp93wdNmVo1UAEWFVuHdjaqkIh4aDdT7dZfvm68rO9u1ZG8BzAfGgd1lzqscYAMDRhkfCTWoUrfcavRT4SXPBKz5gznetydqrGjatvvG8Bc5yYOOGhobmGybb3SNPfh@9jaRIn62DMIzu2Nlc70p8sQ3j6nd2Rm79EkHpO29rbrNCNrZ1f5NOEdzTpPJ1wp2Wk00ySJ9JpxWdMOTy5Om1Gv08cd06SYbHycx6cewju5iIzzKTcnupreX@ECi4vN5vtakxa6B82m692lZAaN20robfB5uVzdRgTAwMobGz@VitD9eYZQGz/og0421MMBBHIK9X8Q07fgPHRVsdgOdTFc3gdgs3UUy7HJGY5SSDTyZUeE9Emr5J0Jfo80O3BBx4D3W03sk8IykjP1Y/rT@5q@yORgfSDpLNtdxSIWsYxG9HtoqpFK2CUC/9EeCaIOV@nHYfj51CnZ1WHN75/2@23HdU0ZzjuideCp495S/CQ8nShemCzPyPKxs44dEZt1N6swyfmzJpnS/eIPuWUO/jRH/OMabMTnA3ZNuSrerNabls4PUhwWSZ7Sri1wvYI7GTrfm9pfGx@wmiutPF6f@P4q@S5jC/aC8AtME94Rlzvmn1fHkoEGGPviIJJE2kNGsWiVMfYmSeYryniGTFdRG5Y/NFefhTyvE0lIkb0IunadmI2H0bWNPcnhl/u1N5vvdnZIdALbx09Xn6yt5xK3W3/15Pcj6mHXvex1bEDzOOlpnGSNki1SfHikWJ7TU/ZnBi4WkRHO802n8Uf4eUjsNrKWTBBkaG6M@FY9mOjlQ9Ahr9gBx72c4deZI1MzgJNpqovWnAfXrOIHpCsxD2hjlu6Ye@0afwA7Gf5miCcN0gykWYydGRPn0uqC5V5@x5iK8uKGHfcgi583fCxu3BIa8FYX28/idi2/ad62ejEWU0aMV@52LklI3JvEQhm7ip6M7LfsZ0RvALP3MPryV81v9PhRO7hjd3dBPKqNDoiMO0lJ7FOnm9G60Uca8jGCmcCpmqnpucIuv6uR4rGnt5MTxyDWaGBUEJkHNr5ZwOuJH5HJKtkC9sWyq74Ip8J5B@Csa47V78S5s5qjoawb/yH63XilUAIrcXIiVLtK6siZLB8TPxaGnBky/Sl6MPx/Ik1mwH9OK06CnlLLcgJ4J0oyVKEVLV@ZKNGVOWiwTjdSatqfPqZgvtkdc5Y0TJ/eXMv9GiKB7p2x@fCR3R52nBkEAJNjY8Mev4lJ2llAS6cXeVcXxzlJr3U@cJSeK8xUMQW3sHbssdrlmbMVvLjKlb0mq8LXVFS9kIXbCY96WjJNLOXV/Tgv4Fzj/6P4gDdAkgHPXHomVquTnFXSo8zIAe1qyZpw2onHJFJLv914avdAWS4yM7Jfn3wZQhHoDeAz3U6O6tJXYp6b9bjIM7E6ZC94cNCOZTImH@2y7oQNMbsh4Nxv82YIAr@MrjBBdAU6u@pLoSnnPhuKoJLU6jD1Mwhx6/pEWp5WrxLseWcSHJpg/64nsQFC2dUyOXxx8KExtK/L@@pNMCaUu3drtrBY8cFB34PtIiqTbQldHkFuWv3@kFTHAO0mHL1o7Prqg950CHvxxVD7L6T5LBrqHQmj9FM1UJtk9c7TjDjlZ9TiaITbCm2f@YObdB7CQlTck1wX1pRDzGt4dMNsOkbXD8vKeZ6mPCeasFtSJuJztaa@fpVcQlDtMjRkCkZxsrhgm02uB@cOyfC76g8/Y@6HCtRrh@3EM6kFkvcCpZMaPfbx2BpJ0wf9mHc0qCuwA5JQoiwbaYmhKs3RTzQ7abumfOodE75LuSXfX0/CpMZaiipKGVfXTsy3VqDOBJVWtGvQxFloeWWVUZm14Pp242KMvYVmj61V/lMvESkVUSKq943qiCeRm8nTRzzpTf7q/Rijh77gjFuroEAYOivOVaflHOMHm4IPUThs23uipMm0gwG233jp0@8xL5qtQ@32rxWM4nBMK4BWMbouMoym85f@Wa@51e8Gp1E/CmidBo/61yLx8DjmR3TY6bB/FXP8JglKaWVqj9Nn8S8jbtjwnpxLrluuueJROHBsM4XRcFw7EzcRvHMOI8A06Czz92DSR1pS5vFqWiiXvX/K9nhld/3Gso/KswrLiT4AaAG3MWFBIXdIR3wxybp8uj6V4WReBgvHE1VQgXuDxV4G42dEIj6GyWBskJkyS7AbgZXZjRgfta@9NvsgHMLRUrgdIsRQ7PBnL0Akb5IiP8JSoKLKT0tWUTlFuYYfQjyMbyb3ypN/MvaEwJ9Av/xoFrfMYgQWcR3jbSmW9Yr2Mkq4sHlgxDKaJTFJseg06lnXDzmex/Uk1Gzy@CZqsOUPKUXazd4UV2JEOrTwQZhBp0kipzl2Maksq2WX/XZABamNnNLNDBveZj/Lgx@HuLJzBsG0pSE7FtI3kapFVEKk5AnzWhtl8al8@4hZWblrr00QsDrL5MyK2e3kjebCN1AimV9xrNUfkjDOT1BPm3osx6P@YPmO1LtRdsz0zDaL1i3XvdUQWJitSpPlgzaTtjrG43g9N4nPBNNkKcaWZsRDWL7yc8Lmk0S8rjYx3qrN8S10uIlmqd1UMqkk/d2WsY9J8RIWvWaiSYYU4w4npevJ96MmNbx5swTRMGV51WSJ0YTIaI7l0QI1QaaESnenEHOfxn2CHm2iHOptE@3s/rmRqJNGcsblqUnKOLkEPeG4HZc2SS4NOjC@gJs40XATIZUonNfemI/yyoUTOBlGggCEVhwW0n0o2cFNO2uCjzg6QMdpwlqoDElETxu2hUPi9D8hGHvl15s72uKhOS6Uj9cF0nUCiVYVnGseJHPfnF6PmtcMZYoUNMRnkCJp0ZRsOrt7q/5sWygfQZDSnKwtfUseGuOqh4QN/bGTmtfQgdOqdMnMiMoOhCaLBhoLtEo57YayXIX2Fw2F42HdoIcRLSDks4Ofh7oE3HmvlRJqo8h1e4wsria3jDZXFTakSMpQ8g7y66Eoqi4vXAlAKBhT@WqZIMCtKWOPQwF2vWNzXgZR3UdUsFrGsKSP7BU1tfOckQ6i6gyPV60cpVk5ntkwCjOBkGIxO0@KCOkss7OkUGiim4mLlePJ7PakOUghNrwvFKeu0L2SpWHSc0JAjvRdclOJclRWXklzMCc@XnUziQl/c@qzkpVamkwl@iQYHhXKk6lPS5nUTLUrK9mimZJED9euNZNIpHBthBOp8Of@8dUU2@V5YhNqLTIyWoa2z0Ykdlpl0rrN/zVWz/lSttExDDz7ZrhZfjUlxErGKft8B@xqmY8M4Lv9T7fWWKYaTHSsAPZLZy67OLIgZI01j6kezcJK13jaSxwUmDVtv6PeH@7sZNy@noyNodF5OFwtlUpg4hPb@b2xrcZWUtQvZnMXOxfdbnFw9Zfh@5Miy/4w5JAAFbOCDqlLaFDEfn94KpEhgANlRe6CvsiKtf5Fp2OHYMAJJTqPuk1yam8IiiegKDF6eX/IG0AMUk@wv6CBaN8vKhl9V4EomhqKOYai0jAJvsyb0zMiDz50YJ@dnFQxMAhmY81E85Zb3fiCGQSRTbiz2H2x@yU1T86/Crvdvqc@IAI0PAUsfJsssLNjFyhJFpww8u3ei5j90XoqvIy61r1iZLF5HeDMxGTiTBi/8PCNvx@e1q8HTv7o5zxNK9Tkh2jmQ/in9lT@NO9qZ/F3ACt8SGjfKfd5MHBaTKfJzDTV6xGcPhFGj8rezLVPJovLe2KaZrfnBlFno@uzswZqusu6gPFlz93LLbkhe0Lc/Kfrcgc0LAkMjRN8rtytBK6a/fPE4uWo07mbVOQwANKx3yURJRLKnxOIfAbAI1APP6InvGj/VKBhvTPhUEQUHATrmJY7KNBEgVzufqv625VTq9XU0uDhQ1WrbdJDoaBqmzW1jQ@bm2qb3jfx/kN1ZXV1XWTutvuFPm6aj9/UJsHgHc6HrbPhNr1SWhX3xmCtjS5eKlaXvPWlZvX5xnpcPKpt4lo/Pf3nv/3X//z3/1as6Zf/gZdNfjn6Ocnk@35xqfVl6Ydv63g/2j5eXjo5WhocL5@ug8v@zl7D@41RIUjNR/3hSW5RZgHrK9uRmnU2e5/RRZUJG3geDD@TdKmoxVZcXNRfY4kcxTJ2sRVa30PcozyhJbwJOjC5lCckFgnoGNvx1DutEAZ4NN8QJQkX2IFKeTlbMRv3cAeTZEhOVRa1Jx7WWS9D3GlJPSngLi7NWIWoF4c97IBfss4rzcvlAvqNRk3Nv8Wf38Snm/1r9eCTox6U1ANPPcjn@ae89oy@ukvFCLdzJRstB/J5j1LSowWYGao4YkWP1w8ca2eC3LncEofsASTjpoIzyy04L1n98WUZCbgWn@YWENVUyRYJHzKhyOKXpd436pYvlONbPnPVhhWFpl7FcGXWiUrSv1CBglgMAdKaz4UglT5ViZM@vpGMp6L5ovs6x9GEGDDIuv9yh8c9PtBctNTTNs@ZtRTCHLH5vHzF3Lgul6EZbaRI/SkCfKAiy8kS3yRcXlzOiZW31UpuptzCttunmU9sHcbhyNimS6G/KYsJxJrbJtxST99r0Ybccryi8lFyvGJVlZ@0/VY5q8j5RXcUDfR1Ba4dA@pLUts3GUnoUQYkcMRnf2V6hPFGgfEUNdEtEixrrNp9NF1GQk9fTacOdn05ObKIUPzZobH9dWJsu0W@JWLYQXiAkUpM@TpB1I2115UhE/s0GJ4gOmDQ4YBqIzk34/08RKedwLjfSZD2GTKbnKfjmZqyOBgGp@eBpxZ3@4fDYNygaYs0n1HLd6mFcMEEJDD4dNWzmmcQlhbpLmGKJE1hyyEEL@iOdXg06dt8cucEXWqGgna7gkGQYSemZPg101cTdEy5@js6wUZ5Sngnp5FaxLLkhaWRhpS3r83wMJsaOjlTgz12koGTzwmqycg0vKALXWCiPeeDX5LkXfgI0HXn9S1AfRVh7Rnqx@x0GvaCzOQ06ObMRf/iupJ5EeOZQ1GKNVJOQ3lSTiPeASvSI3/OeoGQucm4M8otOM7Cp1iHc1u05xF28p3Y4hcDFSUB6DiAGd8MUe96kQjLiRkqjYHhqwZb/hOETjc4JfzGV8EYrPhp0fnxXtE9@vlT7/iB86n39dPvLmOiRbKZZQtqUR9mG4mlxwrNjEUv82qs0mLjavBTL5vhU0/JHRaLBIRI0Tn6uXj8tUgIfVp03QfFT4tCkEyXAZPi/PqKAF@cQnMxi0VxMbfgPnBN5zs/ll1Fcyv/og/lgyu/hIVZVPI2Pa1zhh0Cxfd0f7uQKydx8elK6fFK@TGthE7D68IwvMB8W4gvTsJrUiViLGdp6vn0e4YbMoT4dh0H6/TxmtopYU3k7kmsLylpEaqHOdeTS9iKyvjCE5SfqMzuUnHFxU3yBDh8xILfU8RyJi/7ghLTQYv7HMyfcf8c9QQx5Nrk7RDhSFgZiI0Ib6EWANkEX7mJQ10zXJb5npOvtuC7lYFQ9xYXrdmi1@8VtLLm@svrUKJxa6b7tPS0NDlGp4ZoZoQuaWVq@Z4qb/z45D/@@95vi6PFjZXihyH9jhZ/W1x7uiiP9EBvj8zb5eLG4nNkW/u2OC7SGpgen/zH/6TyG38hOEgZP6c/G6sG1tp4caNQ5SJfFzfW6KG8skL1/q9//Vdqw5Ks2BCLdanpKUZs3VBkK@gx71K6aqCVsixdTsUKX8wCDLEwpLU5vcAw6nrlaYm36Ra1VcVlqD1fGXsUPcWzYdaITYVkJ8PYU5BmJAWqqKAgII0JRUdZthvGbAPMm6Kpfrnvr8W0AvhFm3MkVSamG/djmAwtybKIOtCRGmk9Lw8bpR/ziXlHJW9sStaNComlnZa1Tx@tEzu87YejqJW1kjDD9bwVXIUnPvjQD9sXtKbqxd3@r8PiJbHkeXnlabGDzf0i23EXBwypMBj7v5MiqIMB0cKQjU49NaQe6J/DhZfH0YJIod9JzqRMPEnSsgdhS/awsjGJKYvc8fPkeBjN8VNV2uG/pMAjcqYOBGnFSvvUo5J7@xWVf5hklHy85nWBzVs2jtUuMApiDTtg2eTnuA3YHTTt8WvDU76ExKXgdV2y@EG73Qx0mpNbyJtQaV5u4SzsDqr5jrh3h@9UnJho@ouaeSOUQoQdhEKBBR1gnYejgJbo1Tx/wXo8rQFuUvRZa@IqLiVrR@fVq/p2laOuzKn6Sqq@oh6FlpDWk/CM5Y1N2dlEtlSxVTkMmzhSm1kx1RaboM1Dn3@AQSzd0ujgWoJuDt@AJKqlzdFWZXa3ebwWJh65CuXOnmwtSuTq3GJ6@dEzOeQGNXQn1OtLZSQg4AW3Agtlej@QGxBVE2Y06uXEn99EsvHvocFwG/bgStR2WyfOR2Va6l0i9k004ruUikig/craNtg5mT0S0ImLrSQEbR4bL3kXLNWp8GKLM5ruqHAYaOMSKp@XfaqjlkrCy3Z09FoJFEEf8qXyyqPHq2tPnj5DlLMF3drZYFDIxypgcBYQDNaoHVpk43u1ml/OyyeEoJ6uEtBngcUBHMy6rlzXuH2@cu9VyyUNrJRnWFccRkOK6@1KBplCHIY@ZgRaozjDvOP8WDlCw44/td2v9D/xt/EPyAxn3NEGQnqrH96mnqly5@JwoMqCmZ3iOI/gQcXVKXbesN/Zh7eJELauwvZU0Wt4gBidDfsXp2c2d/jatdUhDRgiOPulxgrqZThKHYxZWEEX1RsODev2RdXAO5puAYxyMSVA5xPgNMy038pAW5pidCzTJATPmrixiiNEy3TUZmfmzl5f1Xe3JxFbtMPQMVzftmwl5Y49mcGBDGL1Ws09JOpqbxd8lVTLJC/jVZkFXAn5ynwdPsBd6RYCUVtUMbKa9YaRM48sZebF1LVpWpT6EXjNgFku3U5Kc6/VtAIEMYJQ7yYlQsxLznNskqU42Z2McQpezlcsG9E3URyzgzldWd7VFqWciaMKLORuAIh9m1JeGlKqoEf5sc6Bl6W3EcxRbkVja0CbIScr1XBmTg4zwVa3sTjARtRxQwu0v7G75antOv3Z@bDtQVHerP2Edichnm/Gt6zxLVdUY8d0ge0tlm1uYTP1G64oEbOUtMPYFEEI345ERQxTrwH1xo6mvQzqo8zYPk65AuwaaCXc7I7qQQJHL7wHsqAX74krDr6uw98qsnk1LWkSlyp6WMgW1/yBbdFkIa01gSSkvAOIlUkQiaOWlNsXUoYXC3TWvAO9djGM3diZzdMZlpUFFantO0Uie5Znb6TMPLZY0WyxUkE/zuML5tu5vHESdvr6LlrCHLfwxr0/xhuFuzNH4f8L5qj/c7jjkeaORxXIHuGOxG043@jkMOz9GRxzMuY5uNmOTiPsD3WsVzSi5FkAWOABQ9whpcRyCW27QZwoZ3bCw8n5CEZCK6u4GPCHGv9YN/5xBTKXH7fD/1cbX/gHN35VN361grlmRs9r1c5yt/6PaXGqEjrZDzO7F@quZHP/aEvXdEvXKphNZ3Tz//WWFv4PtfSJbumTCjwmyIGDuK@fz82iidQOthqN1NzCz2mnXQ7i2M/mShdrr3Y1T4uHTvciPqtCW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OItIbEOTtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStdj@gJSoQ0b2wN9UKFFHJPEtPTJj/VH1Ppm0w@d8VZZLsOlomDc2sBLSvCspsOcdF8dZDMlbVkXtlmH8hq63D/9cP/ImQ4Dz7rW2iEPLr2Kux2zUxiL8EOE69TujFWcwD7QK85MqyiycnIjvRt74RdFm6WauzYYmJenL1IkKM2nP/RWuoc@oYVlRtbRkQbX5c3qyqY5prlhXyhtkum2U3WLf5DXPpMc@mzitrXC4ObSBXoDT/Ni@k6bWV1dd4cIKV8/GAAljzKP2dU/W8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/pw0xd)

[Source code.](https://github.com/Suppen/fish-interpreter)
Run in console: `node fish.js polyglot`

Suppen's ><> is separated from official ><> by calculating `x*x/x-x`, where `x=1516=6568408355712890625`.
It turns out to be zero in JS, nonzero in Python3 (at least inside official ><> interpreter; I was unable to reproduce it
in a Python snippet). Python3 and JavaScript differ in handling of large numbers, I don't know why.
They both use IEEE-754 double precision floats. The difference is probably due to representation of integers.

The code:

```
ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
      ; :n@04+7*aa/
```

Answer (score 1):

## 387. ><> ([Jo King's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209524)), 16625 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                                  @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$])++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{'4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1)# \␍exit(0  );'''101ssss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
@#85""C""Hata;re7^;s0::1''Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F ._#giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?4|>8053在ｕg=101-2\0C0+---<?MLot ~<p>3:s4oya 8:n?\let d=    5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;' + #.---.>/   >"473",,,@
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        & @g+$,,,"369"<  >"673",,,@_     $/   v_v# +1y2^;v;k09<
endif#           @,,,;A=AgRA; "377";AC_; ""( #;"573",,,@;4H'R'T'I'<)>"863",,,9@
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@    @,,,"364"<9\
''';'#{' #'}'}'#         ^z;@,,,"366_";k0<^ (^#4H'R'T'I')#;@,,,"372_"^ s;k-10<9
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~##        @,,,"371_"># 01-k;#< "873",,,@;z0k;"763",,,@;9"482",,,@)print 379
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUlKpVLd0u6pUXaW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixp441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7N2e7uunltawgYKg9dzAdGfbEqwgxpjJm6fZgqg8M1jetieGmmWcYrGNYzhn4a4xtT@2pZ/TqYMsyZhtn7NDumj2AwCbOiWGbbw0X/HKM3Tesi9HFhHWd0Ui3ex4bu6Y9Id88Y091sPSn3ROmd7yJq3cnpmODV4GxF7aljzo9nVHwsWvwSEUGoLonFGfZp8TYY8f1DEjB6Rqe56BjGRx113Qe7T356Ep4NcM@0iFTY8uYXUleVdmnpuH2rsbQ2CfHDx5cdc2yr0mOzR5cz5KaY3vTiXM4uQo/z/YGhq0zTS7L2lXPAiBzYlilTClz1asI9WlMzO5SOuDxwHShdnW/FllXt6G2sC63mDEaT@ZM4vWvW1ZYtx7TPTb1prpF4ezpqGO4QUBvorsT0x6wM3MyZJOh6YXxKLQ31ruG1DMsc2ROjB6zTIjk9H0oANrusRNjfua4UOU@TMe25hDR6Jp9E6ME@QCAeCUmQ4PDGelzqGR7Ao2D6cyDbFhGAC0pxCD8faMzHTBnOhlPJwzy1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadYBP0AyuZ8NDdtvzABOBhDHDs/V6yllzVi0eb3XYxlox5CPE4OZgDXKVoVls@DOHBewBqGCHPnAqF3zMhozqDOoor5TYflMBvwPQhfMrW55jp@Z5ayhpw19leoM4T51nYGrjwAbPYNw@snhU@Z1HRdscGNY3p9uAtPVJ2x7m8UPntyPs3pYLbLbEcIqqrFzqIJY4MlOdWsKLSRaEw7UjxvGFrDK4hvxCosDWrQMy@VYDrptiWl5QJKaKYMB@r@WVeEuMK3Ecir0oHw8jen0XX1gWgaHMkAoRWz4Wp5p8MzkWFYt8ZADx@rzYF1KrMiyJVYosmKeFeFZZmUNUkPQOaaW83AX4AZoZciKCnc2xwEt2j20U2xr@6yvj0xr7kMn8F2WV1kRIEJ@VYCslQACvLNZvLNwU7aWryjsyRCwPdRPAbxkmSdIjYyQIGEVKvBStrYUoohIcnny3hCTB9QB0vIlVoTkC4CJHGQBMKuVIPl8hhfEGxqW5UcbehiNclvMwA05LwIeSoD9DOAyg8gswg12oHcaEDYNqJgGhEkDYqJpYM5iEhCuAH4FqMqCj6@h7p1AQjwdrUfIB4oOYFTENhIxFZEEEKC2WBbqrMBy0BCy2BDyWQb5h7wUCwzoWEllpRwrFRngs5xhUDcq5AtbiQr0U4X8qAgM6l@FBqBCnlTAtgpA1WyeCRFkq1n0h7hZiAuoUXMQJwdmqDi1gDfEg5ahQpIqpKlp5UUjhLxpeShvPkutUytA7RbBD/CmQV41aE4a5FYrgT/GLQEOS9h4i/E0R4SOeIBaweYO7RCQkYf8EFwIC2atmOX4063xUO8gteYxO32MWsBuUEA0QtQMFg/eOcQmZCUDYLAXQPY1aAFZQEcWqjabC5O3VADSQPBGzyQCbZlAu9QQQ8U0NcjX@niyQJtaoByN55Nh6KZxNwcIpwnEzxjo3XnoCb0vHXouXAtZdNWI1i4AZXLo6gFldaaetQASGnIaJWWcmtbCrURuPUPv9U1v@G6R1xwl0jH0iW2eLFLJ59MRpOoRjwJ6LDkVs9GwE1OC4WowRNOiLFoRw4ydsIKWsqyqlL2O0Z/aA0MqlyL5I5/J1J3AwLJIs8ydXXMwgDF5AUdNUzFpoFw45ymHVjY7EUJHxC6m6ZowfN9l3SEwFKFnmcMvlxcwshrCmOsdHNUl4MJgFCjjuNU3Z6xzt0ujxiKDWcJTd2iOg8CVtYEjlUuJzEqFSNsgzL0tZULSjFdLfu2YdiLO4knhUoCxhnOW0ZEaBrRPcZTCcRebLoyrDnENC/KZsIORMQlIWx7kYdS1gIxCpXR1HIFxPDJoPA3gmBOZQSLABhrOKbKtNCguJePRwNlxkUsFLqdnuC7DsMDaemkaYr1pxzPeTJGPWuSrD2O2AUN7XzetMAM0jugTYgDgHfcgvflytvuuM6LBZoRDqOU44zXsCgzYZwjooXNmLLK@GM/18dgCrgncDc60QWbOdOK3iTmPpsozBJEwHlQ4AKSkgNswXaNLuPeLDrGzwJcsZ7HCtPrdLEK5F2GnstBZgNXwMI49tawK8DlGl2XrSs84VdCFs1zLrBbmIWDCgJXyQXR04JUx55SLENJdTSb27jioWc8ZLReNj6@HYdGHJjJG1pk@h9rrw9BqzPQRcPQM2WbouWwELYbXINYEyCxYrEPWc@z4JIRy5gITC4UOS0KMMuJkYo4MkH4ciII1nqNM4@hOOevMoSkTtnIyiTs8J1cQJQtXEcUdchEH3lmA3etNu4g1TNu0qQUBm@Qhj@8CqeRuwsRlzaYOtwv83NiX8GQ0YMDnmLWIgODx3u5z3l2CiDyqYXsgVngyM1H@gpY/cPrQ2M5MKDsQLIi6gN0lJCAKQqeZ3JUFQjk2oNGJxUzWHY8ZuMOgBM3zQaYELKjz2mRvwdMaggjRnbrunM3GUBPmCEJNuk6/D633rTEeAgg26rHuvAvdEyoZW4/Qc4jAdMfLxVzYNg0IY6NQsv/0F9nAALQDw9pH6RSb/KIA4zEVgVCh25yZtXXAFBahO54TWoTYIkbfcWR07zmGR43FcU/Cro@JecaAugb0s/6CGI2QOYdWapNQ0QPK43cvhI8JCisLg0n5reAjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdI/1QciOsLAoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXJm2hF@/@gB8vvkKvnAZG8obO6y7SutBoKGLSfCy6L8g1kf@2KIjrTWl@QlYjxCkZNTFmt@LXkIcXoldfEVhlnKwStxTR7G1CVQ@CEiMZ0gKUHqaHaHSAsnSG2I34be5k6vFx/cosm7Iyb1w7QxNyqQHUFWQifMx3oYEtzWdUDy2EJY9SUHDLrkcAto3RutgOyEmbR6UVdZ0WUgircBHTm2swIqIDOEi0GWfaguqDE@R6qhW2FjpO7iLdUREuzF5BIOZDCGjseOCz2DE505zSRQlUValy@AJ8KxIimze8tDKwwZcRzwJzgKQoSxpUNbwC6GPRUkKx0oBRAxLiADzXN4ipEMU68nWH7@zoj088YEY6ltGyic6e6cA4HiwfAMCc2Z6bpABk9xkOBjUDCYyNROYUzQez2krIgO6vdXE5exRe9PO@bsqhTeRUf5tSec6i7rowDuAtMBnSgR73vxZJXcKWbES1Sc8UShqPwpQkAKJEOVJ/og08Mg8QAIzfO53U2IS11MTDNxOumXxCQYMCLn0djHICpczR2KD9hoRifQr8lWZQMYviUJnhK6UU7QQ5HRQ3eBz4BOCFJmudzr6OwCqIfLpNk@F0UCkUSVc2Faht0L0/IRgXmJllfmSXhulwxSZFTDEmBwKjkNEksI/EBMUEQRHBTFH1vRgbg97kd8DXec2jQPxxKcFUmy85D5hQEgQZkxgfkwu@ak7bMrd@8GjMtGrQaNDbgpIJu9ZFSiDSYsZaDUEFgmbsRPRJ44zyfYNxJJKC8GvuS5AbYJWmqtzs4nQxd6HNkvBQgEaBVsbMkBYv16fmKeTHtXK9pGRwwkYq8DpsnsTsSqAIM/7w21m7AaX8IqSL1xxCo2XoxPoK81XnLFChX9YK7hIftb87MSqeEE5sBvqytRxKP6bosGvT/vWj5LwE3Q2Tk16kD2T/yJrJAQpX2eIOi013oqB4LdgcNhT/eOH9b8vsg9lY5pV5YcLKerW@S8icHFIO6jw3vP9p79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4fvtm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz6NnXrqIEOCFEB6UAZryvsDQ8DDBdQkf3hlcGYTZIpSDJMEoQlkmHLIAZGjDr6K8H@Xk6ffsWK@9qpsa@O@bMmuocQOCoHNpBPBk9rzBggVenz0dEigtcqGnjQsPCFA0Z5Ocj5JqvZoZY6UiT@ejowcGzGoH159UkCqJ4E@CldLcnQ5u3piCCrwoD5A9MXZaSFxlHfpryuhLB3e4Sghd1y9bABwAo68gOk6xRUDRvCHnfv1o2cpW6YQsgO0G4yldG@aHul81oJB84xHVR5F01ipLHYrAKnVaOWKHv8rDVzeeNYq4cHba6izR7UaC0KADjQMA3uuB14knoIi@4SJ@t9rP//NG1jHvERIIoIAU58ywmU1qeJaD0Ipks7in7IKE5liF/ShRPZGJSUeLBuoDc9Uj4jIQ/mJmTRCbJ32oSwkLqe3uH2v0gsD9lTTMZJDSgLI4jk9vH9b2uB23Edixn4LAtiMO5wyBBYJvWFnNv4NjXakhHRyxqDJcIgf7ixI0@hrHGfEuCI8WKiqt8sVG3vTOg0mohi0giDBEohcLLr/VTHdC1KPfzw88PYBBR85lMaM7QBSiIxCF0oakbcSUHJkFCsp@flQUMlwuv9fbAQ4qs12GhfUIXRtxbeK90JIopKyvDr8zSx841jL925leaFrjwpgWGCMoOnzx9dPjk4PHeZ82Jls8v2XOZcgEQB@l1gBeShxxv2Fu3eNfEYiG4GPQNF7sXUIEpCCjBatHUc4FwyxhE5hlY02r4QmviY2dox73k1cKcoa/02u7yJvQYOx8P6kcEQbtnoTDi8tVqHM@x/Qwnk7FXURTo5cNpRwahVXnddSx9oFA8GBgsS1FRdDk8wnkNb1UMyIw3N3gMPrkFrMOcZhB1a@SA8EJr3kgaWIKDp1kryxwMQRbGhXHDTcphC6bSKD2QEEBWVsKyEQEmG@DWfwf1JPKm/VVVK/F2rWa0nCIGwZa6P4Td6BsgOiVgtAJUJK9YWfNu8y6bA5VGSFeBxJi8RZMcHsOxwGLASNKsKcr5AXKIWuB8KdIKwtGbKc7mApVS8plcUS3kFRDLQEwDnlXCOTdppE@6Q2niSABPcvo0bxBphX2vq9t9ecs3BJkFvu8OFDXbeNls2i1g0Jt3KW@47tyYtxpqK1ll16Ns@eGTVWi9S8XDths4QNslIzRNerM19KynXydnPZ16V48pk9HYH3OkMXu8B4zUWwfodc@I9j2MoEQ9la2lsAoGfqesmBCyMKqAD8SUAh0KRlpoegrmSwKmF9lDaDlAtyIR2GI2g5eD7@@I0BEUurHdm07cozUS5GtwttQbAxJpsrmLVNrD@cEJjI5hy0cqDZWLRJqdGXGcR9c9PlsJkfw1/iA@yGohBJqVD2ek7XBXAzQCikXiOVAOaFc4bTpczDKi0A8tDRKkPOHkA3AQNq0eDIDOQGRekD1eEJ4SuSwX6cR2zmyE1jFYSeqYEz7Z70xdXOs2e9GyQfCsxsMANCpchK7TonjH6PJZVh6ZSgFCoM5GxsjBqQTgrogUGFQEnS@ooyzo4Yw1dKuMhCuGAF9iu/tAxboGny@SRihEQZM6YPGJq@xJnyu69BZa8w28FRY@UsV@pR8HCFje3kCzJP4MKHEnzogCfUrzLeh5L2B3BVwxhBJDCxP1mjM27KsyH5cIE8kqbUOIx/ki0Hl8Y2MjXonX42kw7YBpG007aEqBaYdMEpkwnIwmipEmE/o2KAa6teKXjQDyLNnCNjBDzuGtOU7ojUol20rrDdV/a/hOQlUA5iG0hC@AE0/WamhMJsX6Ga7ZAP8eKfs@tp3nXdcc@yj4GBgCbvdxkCUkgHiP3LxrVFE2vRkjo5oLQqOBLGbCjTcbmWared7spZqX8TTGTlb1GsiHQLwmiZE8cJ3pGBi3Rq4iAW1LNrKVVrVTi2fiW4lESbIgIT2ZvFNKpnSO60TcgDaVaDbjgFIfO43u0CV4s7SWTIaIgnz0TZAyLCsRl89LkH4n2Uqm4hA3GU8DWa7F44AXWnD0qNA4I8Ab0QNzBqiEjglDXHRNgQgkLU5hd/3cGA/nbjRAOOsGXDbOoC/2quCWHqTiUSr5lsePMnRLkn7A9/JwwNzi5B3yS@M5p@4Cz2lTWdoZFYy7p1J/5Ex05RMZhCY5MlzGN@KKJMFISD4cEhX7selhF9Ztw5l60ZnGlROgmDq4Hg@nQCyD7WlpaFXmWDC6Q4fFN3cBOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKHIBLpIW7FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGj3FO3JE@rBuvQhzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrAcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiPDN6ggX0ow/kUeZ14Ro9ZUugVVrHHcIIAaVBSqyFtTXyPRTHG/fkyQyiCgkccKOeXLoDpvOM9TRNK3Tz/Urgh60CkD2ESkKp1AYRN/CSVPBM@pV8wKeFAhn9ydH9Az53QoMtDq84j9YeOb0p8JW@3PTMsAdpdgDtybSdkQloCOK/PbGeOc6ES/lgWTczw4VmczS1dJrzuTotc2O8rtNxLJoKuinqIvzU9XRL55NQge/eJ4@B139x/LwmVyKBFP10dGPaOA@5OlmOz8PomiOttwbLQx5vmOJmXsRxK9j1iWTG9yigx9Tf8wl1FLgX0T3oUriG4ruX0H2E@z2BV/ZnEcgaOvoByxQQ94Dihjff8VzNXKL7WhksDKdSOM44LnJ7rmrkfjrp95ecs@R8IiFpshbOOXLme0GXZMRolvI8EG4MXQoTBVSgMOH@0LXhihSO726Rw5XFx@EmhKFhBUuLz4BjweUzGPQt5KtAaEEWne/hNIDDHuMqCZFuXHtjXWBCvWvzGdDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyf@65SF7Idf83S42TVAZmfplW263yVG2Uql4tzCp@V32wDiO16Ndhwty4YphSPh8EIKuUNYlAxaWH/WlHDbRoeTbYLFKUqeAqIEzMtIzVnxYPWRVzxCA19JjabszsZ7TOQS3C35OZdZWBUaY/TGnxVA5@4z8N25kwCjg9D8Ynr7hDoDEvNllEJ9TO1@47Vk/gqGTQYxuUrrCB/k0K4i9PfrGuYbrCBk3bQ8qhIXyN7P6/BvVKl9esBIrtFQ0DQfc7ZxUn69II1YMg7lb2xZU5a7FKeOO2hv1PKvrqvlPOgrqvPPcHf41Jje88@@qSRaXEIwkjHla8Sr8VZsD0ZGGdglHAfOZhwp87EnBAnQDsRTCyvKkOmZrRIAtkHGDyBKgsT8kuEWb8wLhZl6RsgqSYMzLk3H6WZkbyU@5Y@mRg2b3N8@XE9uvk6kZ9MjZLf8RcdKixDKzPAmZroB1mssufH9w@ePZOh5XqJ@AGu4FSgO@rdITAo6wodYDJa@Aq704uzOxgniWK7AF0NpI@2Hx8adRUaPcgfkDrSjoHhJsAxiYsvXXCm9S6KyDk0H0G436o7IRyFwBJGEspEwCor8//C5qKWn88KtPgUYRLQnbhbAdyaSXlqm29kDwYa4lshSJwLqzBe1DYTRMU21aS/oW6ES8cgYRHTCCVoNJj0FqgcBBZZq1XlewAgLApg7gCxK4pUFbSLvaYGVV8DZ2BpCIIfvfaOvWxkpHIrtbkKFG0u8zeg8/JH4CKEZdCesTLZzQT192sdmeeBrwVyyv2CxOkrpy8qbJMbRD7nTMGDDVNEdGh/1fI@qeVdWNDJkJTQVAwWJCAJMf94gN9myZ8oP8g8GI0cEkl2HiJdQ5SziwvCIdvUGOEQTCrjlXEZSJ9AmB45UJpH/tGAKHdAvdXfSIJ9timIgZi1vFKLPpyFV06vcKfSqRiNx7lD0z5xaL0nNLUzsppHjjCMPTqxrsfETaj0WAoa5oGH1dblzht1@vRYEYCWPfwFdXKgCXWfFwYmUlee0Yvm1lekvLyJZClZf3sqjbRgZtKbW0JK5RIF7nc65rqggATcFxa8VwQDIoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHBx6WVR9Kv7j9gS3v19tP77P3@jB/i/XjtDGChw5jE0tGHoxpqS@msry4@KFnqsrlg@QT61TJ0QQ6bbQHZ1F4qkW6FhNWhahJckGP5HuKTg1zi0TXwA13hDM@M55yuCwXt1IqsW1Wwgmd11Ya/sx@JJ0fIPCHY9QgJngkyDIhHp4pVgzPgSTETERjJ2e6aCTVOMGjOv9@F0MuVPYFxvrURzjPdNfdMPmcnrHdVQ@M71G6rc1U@mPUcanwxCPrWwIuyi9LQGLAE74C8Ht9G4uvi8gHwnePBeF2wxtCln9LqtVXj21BtLHZLCe9xGHWF0QwquxZ/rgpj@4b3QsB5rpkWPD2yJPnRoKP5uCAX3mkoRpJlX0GzpnTnyIMMv38rCnQVAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vj4@SJMUvl1fHnsldjo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WWWoXhyhzplqT1Isa1xHzVxoRrQcM1TYqDhy/oBMaNjRwHpO7U0t2F6YYmvshHsIywbkbaHzaeml0H2IExU4uyqgVDR2TAIJIZbI1bJITbiekR2f5grkJjcJxECk2rSYDTneCW0TVt6gMIGt@qiRtiI41EdtZhquuc4b2WfRiCaMqfq0e0tytz9QHESbK6lg7j@NrhYGlyECcfb2moZ6Zn0GM1Yk9WZnTStVa6L3eBYNovOo13W7P2TMvx2HN63oSggQtY4M/VDTqKS1O3JZoMj5pvoEHBHodFherWwLEKpYGiw2NtrU/dPtJ9//2hFC6kUKp6C4UK2B/HVv33Wrp@orgnt1UQHVh0cX9rxHjDELuKTPlrL@tLB4IBLtytLtmDTIliygqf6luTMC65nOnz4P1zDB3rUBsMHeM5sdPA3WGEcgkME5ez2D9ParmbU@t9GFG6BrZ4WyEilXtiGTBY0fNalTIto37JGGom8@Ekqm9NjamxUtA46rw28Fj9DULGh2cq4xdj05@px8UBPJoShnrrS4YflGscp9F2IzHRLbNr3M7KLBO1MXDfYxSdn4LhKRquxxjY0/FSrS5JZ/azm1E2HAdd2ukt5Q59viwdKt3CKS3x555B940SE5fwcINYLZ/JZHwGJrLismS5SZLKhnFfm/y5lDC5LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GoSW6BXEtCdLWCfYUuFxWbNM2JnN8fiA17TiO9WVqCogqHhh2QFqVaKvtTTV2jd3xD5GwxdSFhxMenf66SQs@2viyJeAHheabKj26JPRBtSnhoucIF6SWrTdP30QWmG5LBQ@34pwQ33xrrecl/dkQVS7JxRt7HedQnY5h6fw1K@RugleWszfCWyYa/mItLu7yJd3FUnzsClEazwFZZg@klKExMsh6A5ev91BFhv9aG2jm4L3Oe2YYXWV2YHTXBRibQBdsfC6tIUeYpYljg3w1wX1@KKdYuJPUd11HgYNVv5VIPhzpA4PrbLmJUi4mLHA3DRfrFsbVUxcVvoOmC9EWyjjWNwnoVCfG3AveKwE@nnehXqej26fbrnT@Ls6BfkBvX7eF9foQaw@doT00hnzfeGhb1zmgPU64jp2bsg65HgxxK9t4vLTFPYpPy7GsD8EnkkZOKB2nvzJPB3j4FU9ufSm4/KS9/7p18k6fcNqBhrW9ZmhMYVzynIkzNiSyrQtq4UQPf66jocEi9c87g3SjnA8YCd4/L/xbZcuB7kzGY3q1x9bUowdFlejM8m18U59vTaFNkY47kN86o47sO8r@vhVaAl9NYjrmpDvEQ@O8ZRsDp9Mdmrdl2ldUoQRTPtz6QbIrYsZk0n10li0T0OvOZWwvtaj/c3wdrqt0f/aID2uh4QZ@ZdUMHR3Llsb6Sdfjs6FoYhWcEI70Rn54u0LH3ytvpuZkATSylymc3uXLEmhYl3d/98RazorOSCzIsL@rYm0rJSYdGXLJyADDo65LdnmfW6SLZbP8sS5D0VJSjiL7Ur4Muv29PzQ7aEbmbcF9qX0tbVpaOcjZw@nAu04w@XR9D1g0fKyftqC9zJEpaxizdNt/rUOzZil4yBHebeC5psaNayr5GxdVKJxqSbpjwqsNL6i66do5NMsce/zJpP7apTh/LxPI4lfXCzlu5quFab9iekafL4Gg6TYWceS4uBMZeBCpiyvpOIOOxJwzXpxw2c4AiLpksUXgIOw6tmXlNqHV1R@OmdJnT4yBjnutH5kT3Ky5olVQk121vehW2F@f6p759SmUbF1jQ40NfBnSjR7tR9sKeI/1gdl9uFQRYSZ9BPs7Pflrqfmj0/W6OBuaHu5oCg03TExhk@ONGFtdG@SGFSGvztuHyioWHYgfg1wZetXcujOe42mxOZlumlY3JzTL6r/XiY7rNoHdmImz6Wg89fzX6jzQnqnoLPTohNy9MxOAS2@AtLKhbk1Wz1RHplyBC/MHxYVxHTf@uWk5A/Z5KcOAaQMmDJnzFQ3nHgzPT3FDjmuvaImU9gcue@JEh@Tygr2BujWyTDJtc3LzbM5kgptzgjcWho8ceEJBeYRPeffLQpCOV2Pk0e28/uJo8i3jO7S8587U7RpoDPWNRMUCP1VjP9h9jCc6HNSXchaV0rqOBd0LDNbKLtN17OlEcqf2jaNC4cZRoYLapiLNgCW@fvD4RTLaGmi39m1caKCPbGFau2HgSiMzbWDE1tPR5dCBLHGf60l6RluFb4mzh8qcukSu7zur5J2ncxhAPlhgAuI/Hd03urhseGvaT5zHju3AaDQGQjl6ZvAz/0sbPVZHxGiP8FQ74Kd3azLPCeyaQYhzG/rY6ED9WgvTh4xFHPB9faKvGYpobpDkv9B0a1sxrY7hvqZJv4h5nUi7nKGHxoxki/UNhvdBadLtcpYY5@OW@sjSio03dhybP4naZuClPr6ZqsBQQI8PXyiXcSP@0rzASvlsuahHp3yXiNHjSinWldU1Oo7FnzfsSbJNvidAd03DUx6hjgNyK@SYBNyXdyMNKd5IQxaiEXCyp7pHi/SrRY0FSHX2JbYADXW36@BKmG@4YXdORDHBLWQ63NvPNw50APEzoFh6d@orC70tW9aoM6LHWoEhUpvPjA6eCuqQNo@JPrtemXxmyFdlENnRFSoACMgVduoCSzwFaSR5@7C1JEctY9Uc04Mo9drlctqsI9mm0X2r46yZQ/hazE0v@UOZlSdkXDNXHelGNIus6HTSfWVPWt66BgyNZUiToQsyvzK5aXo7ULOyYj1kOjJwkXl5FWYt6@p4Qyqss3o9PSSuriH5uv6AloR6/zh/KO2t5TwRPPyP7n2swCDcLuQC1SNAum5fwYfMT13bf31IC3zqeJO@OTuCfOMpgHXkBIuVhyjw4j0DTVvrCgG1Z08tPvswiOy7GvVIHJNIC7MkWUSuJ4Zk2KcSKYKbXS@Rww99KXuovXdi9CRfDwKuNEiPgvNfYTD/vWIBNUobcbOnqnDEzgo5f/vnKuSeBZQB@C1nIo09eitj7@nho6NjeeypK8envSGejrjGxy0pVtBKmciU1Gvdjax38u1oPdObKPeeq9L@o0MZA6zBN1/RkOCFK3NLr7XznoEWV0VfKwWhrzFZzSA@PH78KLU4oskS@0PXGRnJqPf@8@dpPGny8fOV3tHYD6B39J3Z2uiHB6qaXNF8X9i0OriOeq5IaR2kYwOkUWiMD7lelluZq64zNnrH87HxCQyeSMG9D0y@sLaQT/RTc4C9kJXXIoo6KivLhVwysjMbhG3DDd/r6vPEHCO17NJL4a@121GQc8gqbnY193DTiv9VLoZl/J0IXy6SmrneWqN6hBXd@/tmTFXVdXh@rvehXll@bWUtB1i1Pmw5px@wlGz4wosUOkkTaFWSees@8qI0AtKt4AOn531HMHbWboO5CUDoXFjZ4c8Me67bEq1l3cReVCA2bmq7McjnxgcsSIU7fE5RWfnKNb5wSz1LdMmYvCXhYzcSZX//3uFtEZ75uLw51EdPXrCnuodKSG4OGM2x8QE5XnBGryWct0INeGuXU3sugNJuhDcYr@7PFfZcd3uOPZ/dvghHZ1BxaCflwiEstFEgwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6u3mZ0W9r8EIczX@KDo8ppfEDvv/3PVDWTIdVD@FYz3HpLzQQdnCXQpM9Rn13U6/gwJA1d5FtkcEiulEYfGTPcjsJng1cJ9SvHt8INY18xuX44ucmvdINf7ob0rvmhI8vKGfUGgPkb/FheDr0fOdbZ0JH3ddfwVuw/XpmhmwpSvqEg5Qh19rWl08Kib17P4uPRBf@1srUeGxM3Nx46HTO3sgx7fVQyyR6jsvTr/v52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywe2r0zubGisTeqy/Xe1BlOZkpRcQQWM4pSMR172XF0g7wPMa9sDk@hXZPWdyQLYbBLPwxPPqvQjm@P50vD7HQBvxkxRXyflSwE9BZnbOPHYPj8Yt2PQVsj/uj1vtvo6nZeHEIKoZfXi8F7Suo@eKFklxkYvPni454@HRydHziJtrzGbrhF5ptk6GXOmzSPXJcW4p2e36y9MVyFp/3gjYDaDH4XstH8SJ3cfPr5MEFN@Gk5EV@Hys24sZ06UK6zkTOmm40vPpfEbbKFfW9JDvYlvl53ZXOC8J9jAgmyak7SntNmrWb7fXtcpj4zNaewA2iE04W8KB@oqXjFluGOSQoqztqM7JgvlZyu7z8dC0Zyu9Ruvi0C7SxGtvdTfYY88t54w9CrUKrSMP2mrg@qlhryNOqw4rSuXszVxY9gpLta5e@NdL/Ne6Krm3jlG7QjNwQ8RN1ATjP@sqDwLLJ1ry1vAfPw@C3x5233Jw/r5nTke3ByawqdTtAd0byN9VgObtwfBjHydDx7VvDxo0p0rlnvGBmdj44JCjedf5gDx0@v3bAx14zu2BHk@tiYkyy@qgT5yphRoEVvkduIOV7vXterMpV@R1nqhN3Ru6yfX@uC/SmXogA5kh8QwjSq/NyZJj0Gaibqjc3bBl20legfuxw76GatzRmR8CBxoS/YCAl/ZVQHGlCfyouicHX3lIJGxIKrn8Sa3ouXtUs53YRDWzm3TGHsJeXLAN/1w7eIjBSXn/JD9qozTtqYFH8fmHdia1TUimVlPzZbaD37CqMDVDaeJn@cpc6V@QWINtnvun1CsV9ZJt1JhYEZmvJyDU4c31UANg1KALhWLSico2J@CzGZxxZ/RJFXbBaGpO6qKiUrDJSlTbR9XXAgB52jx/evj04Pnx3vGL541M69LXEhCUwrYhtUAXyZ1sT4TC@3gDlp9rpSftFBYkR597wSk9LygXw09ILRettlS0RaHEHYyzeW7bikKKEhTpEvIniTw18sWBC5w47KDEVEG@jowK11lAqhegjjhokdKESquwzKqExzqwr5u273/1i2vki1/kq@A3@TBhX5E4NPyB4/T8FD2D3X4FKT7YO3z04tkBCzK4aDVnZm8yrJXzXM88V94C9dQ3aedojcX9KHGoq1ot/iAOiInLcVYh1Rak4x0aOgQLsINKMfzYWyyxSfABg/GwUpT//A3lMi7jIYgkhI0HmYpDstDmqaFsbGywY2gk7P6zw08OnjHM/8F9ckYUIQh2jOfq/@zHPf6VlEDvVfA1QndEvCbpDRKiujUChRMLnRiIc@q74/XfJKSvkpDmifBzKOH3nASBvpYD7faMVFZeUWeYJA1j/BuKvrbJICFqQsGXFXC9DTVHuh47NT0T9V5gHvqoyHG5seMWPVJeKrM9/OAiftZRp0/2QNan9oQrS/NVJsWgpckhzUmzTcos/8CPGAkY396Axt4xQAxhnm0CIZxU2GtoibimVeF6USSpHr8WJQBdIZOErGsk4DXNj57SdJX3v/ZPlEGVgXkC5u/45lnmHth@xbf1wfyr3PxSwYZ2XVPkIi/RDKF2V78EPCMh/hH3ke9M2lwXzQJxqNAyIKzMHEE1nRLWMThPgT8loMcLOInGJ1Bp0NygxnwdNDw9w20lUL1sRVGwSaFoLNMJIGPGt@NeUTNbyBdyqgKZlE4DgPRdiAHqGeAAk8kKdBPh1BzXXoG4tb29zUScHzNqhSqvWWXTfpkVX4UZ3YSwwtkQM9dgEAeiLGKAX92PBqNPSk1iVKRecTWOhKvnwLBE/jh8od32ESGyBCCL48jADw3M8JOkE@AafXXJHfyIZ@SbQZs@IEmFMYlMSVHwtbc8cSbQfKCTLr4KxrW34HZ0PgSiHlKPf6iXtBRje5Sv96yF0oHg40R@X5ORBnBQ2czV0TRat@KnCOI5gqiIq5pv4yVrTpp2S@Ftk0Ez/eGKxmyD@ZeVwZo2y8u9d11HbeKqhllEFtt9bjs4EfgACsMSmqJlFbWQXBQpl1tZJL9EfjJQHFSEdQHJAZkCktE1zNfO2NvbPzj8@Ojp82t6WClk/GowoPv17VRTktONVmiIR4u1XCX3HijPH997EFTEItOFCDUGwu@XRL2pJIv5fQS5OC92tWircni1dOtz/CnXKHE1v1ntpqxRpGv5UDNfIl06syE9oJOXVxPXSquwlc/flKUFPCUCep8fm7@W1UTy/LLRAi7cjsWvt4QVHeFlTN7CTgCmpre1qWBjv144LFj4Ce1j/DihF@2L2dV9UdzMopo/1NoxcU4WihB9h4hHpLxBMkAiBVkJgq7tfUecSV@o69T4J765fsCo9rNIhguZmzAeAXUcfC0cqchC2bCvZ3eoe0PL7AiB1jmubzdQCxqq2uUa4xJJwf9kDU844X8/fFaZybRBM5FEakew0uwm1b0BvKQAHRq5u6dTb8ieOmP@CQPaiHPfCEzPHCC/96d84s5gH09HEK5Pr2cGLYoC5ZYgMmAyHmaV81JAJXzNvbMU6kaG9Bqov9cvuDzq5ROzpDw0Zj1zALQ9kUwDRbujqi0WavfFQpM2XzsuUp0tauHGrvgRKkOIov1LqXieLTKgN3TZtHvGLBE/iycrLUgf3eNnn57Gk@KqtkSqpn3dy72rOqfD7BfVmymJPvF7Z6DQeRW1KJevUwlwuwqY6z4Mvp9WLstDT6DvYdaQc38@cR@BEdiIRH@kj1lianO9kTIja6KZsNOkUE@qc520NkulSKCCF3nIjGL2ycTH74Ruz1lCqeEnU8HVs3v4emuOWUOV5RaYKZEk28TvGu4Dx4WaVJMCCMEQpUJga9iEQMyAHPFOIvMGDnHQH8LCi7RvrvCmz7zR2pGDOKFSs/pdFvlO5TLnKJbLFb9Cl6limUHru04OZQXAXqNzAV8P2PVVSgHOQPyVhdiCkF@neDFKN8Yz8tDXRQXZiUX0SAcqqhjAWmh57g5dvBMHNvQV4A8qlRfHD9qlpCKyUKfVwDV7uLbJP4UQinj@x6ugmypLQeNVLtF9hNFQe2ibK81CJZYPqMOIV0hqLIoGXwNzICx7i7apqje2ej@iXwsQMocDgH/2tx2AQ42vwaTnCr/VxP5nP4shs5HYVNWTtnuaiuczVXio1TzLszubTUnabGRqu5s6SFGTN7MmyOTKVu7@qTHs9w4HSlMUWZblFGXr/Pw8/mDrqfkyzwpSz9QKb2bzy2wh@2Z2mVVLb07GaqEhv5m1xFItfdJiT59@9q79LinOTudvxGZCi@0fXYhqDkX@WKXMzncK2dhJGcRPSJexE/YWrpM@wz@Z3/YiZh3NnT6IsHGRxZpNwLgqFkVFacRb8Cdx/xVcXPBv1OW6vNN69y7Z0PXJbM5M0xx7vR7czhA4SC35nIG8fBcoPY@gsCa9SYLCazTrX59PyDM22zMGg@mBXtfwWLi8267OzemDyePPPw2uF3i9fRaJ9tb/kHIqlZCkxop5ikpbz8fwk8x/9pONy/T50/b2n31zpBgb@DrC13cuH6P5uZq/s7Fx5969XC6taRo3P/386S/u7e3l7qfzTxv5nZyU2dj@0z/Z2NC0bU3ZaHme2oo3Tk4@E7VMTpT/7Efx9tOnX/e8evb//Ma7uoqPIjxOWRHoBFxZpoIRnyW4VeSxPvSKvY1BK1djc/q1Y4H7@QZT6zvF//K9ozexSayuKZ@68J7E3sQKpRg3ggFs2cB2GqvHtjFY4TI2V2q1GhiL/@XfQvz6xwAHfebb8KjnA1iFeawu1SjKRaxeAIOqaZDu//2Nb0RyyMlEjdi44NplDbjEXFETd1pwbdG1LaCuUCmjKEE4ezKcGA5TS3fVu2gxwQIv28CPLhiTZgw/Ss@Odhl71kilUi25LcElv6RJIkVVtaaq3gVyIN3ZqtWkLca1oWaz@buo0T1JU1oDB0ZM4@6n/xBXbJVj9ecG90yIFTZ2X92v16FM2Xp2q56iy@9I1KeKJdFxdkWWZq/iIII0Wq8eMa7CuS5mSpqYTqd322SfIa6kWdiS8OLPWCx0wS7LrrotRYEgvmvsy4eLHeD15//bn3//z79Hv@/T/R9QmardM/vKFgQ6hS5Rh2u3UunW62LdFc@baK9DO8pUSpWS0r5sJraAArWeMTXz0UU8n40/5x@MVxlrJik2XJRs3U8e7fXYwrnOXepRN9@DByYH5peCDEtYI3OItWvhYGj1t51LjdN6S0KGqCY11EK@JfFY9eAqs8YuVJOoFctiq67ltSO2257xiw03PebEQDIsBHj081tflK0e@ixs9ahTrB5Eqy/CfNlwYX6FWKOhtAwaEAI3trtR2ShVChVNadfXX9A0o1YKahjGUy92GgsvjtnYAqGxsGledQuqIrSwoAWzLxMOKutDJruplrIFVaz6Jq3NxCo0Ei0raYO2mFHFsLfh/D5cG/CjP1yhFZ8b5OI7U5Dr1warqFtaVsnfKRxoOL7eckXzKsA4wbqdTudttwNch6539K6uTvSpPtPn@qQz7cw6k@60y7DLLM/oZ528U3JmbEZ/WYpl8@pm7C416neNDfaMU6EWSwVXM3Xr9UKW276RDA7ekuTMYkLsH@Cqq5rKtmB8ysADmDIygsyMP1UVWAwYrfPWu63Guy3ooPXUNhHHVl3ycwkvub3bSkmXlw0wV6v@f7seGqt0cRMUrnWZSm2/rAP38bLeSAHIlz5IWWIEVG7XW9vkEybmp@Z7b7eAf5FS243tmrNPt0wdRGoBxO2lXO7upmQw7ULM@iYIsKlNSdrAIbHhDxEQtFVPBYXBpBPAJJyff8gdzznxgrO7wgvEPOjDl9uX9cvG9uXl9jb8t@l56b/B9XL72p9ei2tNmIV/CwlLs6HUm0rTJxUtsMtKHV1kpQmGOrwhXCOrlVoNNMAlt/7b/MvpxTN0wSy3ZMi1ENtiWzFU7JmNbQmxV@@/@F/wbr7/4veRW2TwMypC7Bw7tbKFsmaZi5zwYPZjmz3mlw1mvAMruqDD4zo62vxh43KUorySWYXP@CfUUiEp4/Dbdvpt1BUis1cQ9BrlY6JWKojtlDrXWGxbLBSJ2P3CtSsej/@jV1q5GOfTNKjs4pXneY8juVzkEwJXtYwqqRd1/j0H/umdX1h1/aNfWHcJsYsyMyqAnwTjiBFi0I5iiiJJMFzVt0d4GgIXSiSUSU9rn0kv9iScRNEntAzW5RMEtcODWrlc52s8m0@p82zd34KnCv@DDSgGa/YhbLNf646A/W32s3mticr/Y1LnDf4evcUfO@7i79kb/LHjt/h7NsEfe9zB3/Eb/O118Hc8wt@9N/h7/BZ/Lwb4a34lm1Wr4uY5YSalltXLzZlIGKrGdurNr0zcecUy7IbZa/nftcrmyiwZa37FmHWN8aTCHfvxn373m9@M12pxKU5fC8qpjsvUZIxhQPzkKWPJKtSEmlGhhF68uhv/SoNE9Hy51cAgLfAVYjW2qW6qGSvTzagdtQMGk2VclhlmhmpPJVEmY7DMPDNnmZGj9sBkwC8DJjPTZ5kBy9gZG4KBL5gm7cwETX14DeDXB0Au/Ezc/9tRM10GCVnI1NG3SNU2xsxctJtCg8WZ@MoAWVRW5YxcMFv4BaeG@OpVU9lqaeUSk7HZye3Gq2a8JTZF1OqvlXOsMzc2mq9EGLozIm@e6MJingcCbjWmNJsKxyQgiRB9edluHzy5324rOEw1HztHi//R0ShqvfE/OnIeHzkjB/5HR0fQuYx6ajcFdHx3twZ03X/txOrVnWaFhoVgaIgp2zvNelZCcyEFRF9Dt9SXvBYQ4V3faArxMxAwzkA2qSZAQjmrnlarZ2T4lFvB0EYzOob/M9/gvwlCNZRvzuA6JbBkQ@PZp83QxA3Kp2fg9CkDuSz8gwAYtf5X@Jv/bf0fv2BJlmi0konzy@0EXUn8JZPnl@eX/rOeTCR8S2IbfugAdoxyfllHIwU6B1MjkWwlLy@5GzwTyW0OsA7JbNcp7iIcDByxMElKlj8S/3XfkLR/NeNV4Iu57J3PUD@KiVWmL/bdNJuzTCZZ7QQfLMFVZP2CNjckq/S1ys1OQ2396Y/oozQ7SQqUz1Wr6hbjFi2nVau5wFYsVaulwLKZSJSvX/XMjloA@SSXSyarVbDsBGAzYIW4DfYuxWqsCc/W3bs8kZJ2cRHAzOYKqQzud6pWg5TykKzh6V2fJp8fHtH3XIDU5GP4ISVOShIZ@hoUfnEwLlbEu3cTPQM3mfd29pJ372rlzMVF6DIeg5O65NRu90y33Ub37MWF2BZpn0w5D/ZM6eJCzZRTajzpuIkn@KlKSCohqeyOVqdUy0DptVwRvP0M5Le3C7l6vZADl0IpnsQ1d07iIb9xMV4VY@dUBrVU5BRQrKJzdP8Q9GUcJ9j5ZYwqlOXyyQQQ0iRwiZcx/LlIc/mIlM8nATOXIg@plss8aJLlColSquz/ahsgtQMbxH/Iy2VTua3i1i7wxPjzZqsupMnVc6OmXtbOjQrOul9Wu/5Hv1EninH3brYMKCplqk2h3b6/d7zXbtdgLENWCh7oSNRdQFUxbrxS3aV6VUt5BhXIHaU4DAmsBFhWtK28WkKsCGYfdRwBDgQuPm2wDUGjNz6EMkfVBjiCfAOp9eBiPdZhA7zYAKU5ZjKLLmYx7k/PbjcM5PDL9w2tFJcEvsDFCC/B73ZZ3iZh1H76aG//4DitbUsspj3Y209rz1/ci6lozS/s5J1F@7ODvftHLyDC00cHe88PPjr85ODFU3D32NniCqi8/1y8o6YV9jP2qfDafasbhm5MDaN9Np2evWGvTbNtQu1ZUyiUM3CZZ7ShLGN9Ua4q3F3T01@/1t0xXez9D7/9/of/3fvf@e773/n2@9/5/k@/@P634f4x3N/l7@/@m3Ienz/94p/97vvf/h1w/A9w/xHcP/npF7/xDX6T/Y/h/k8Rtz/270g4fgsA61d@@sX3fvTTL371B3D/S//@wfX7136y@v7@t9bfGO97v3tzmO/@W7h/j8MKwn73t7kbvq@F/20e7ld/8P5f/Dv@/1P/h8bfef8v/hgfvuWf/uBP/9P7b/57TSv96b9@/63vvf/WN99/6zvvv/WPtfe/8a/VTPTxu@@//wd/9Ye/91d/@D/S/8f0/L0P@b//wT/9i//1L/73v/hD//4J3P8OTD/5i38PXeVv/@CH@P/eH/ztH/0Q///zv/rbP/j1v/2V/4kMv8kN/8@//Df8@de/9h//5re@81c/@cbf/PpP/uY3/@Cv/o9f/b9@4z/@9X//@3/9T76Jjr/5k7/6o1/5y29@@y@/9c//8ptfrHl@@8bnFx/g/sU/gMuH5/ND4HxIub6syxc/V37@PthYpALtBFr3L7//jV@CBv4vGHv/7R/j8UG41/x/rKkU5sfc9v8Bg3a9zOiTARPcv/7@299FFP0PgCL4h/j6TmhZ8uGW7ywsgNbfWhHpl3/6xT//EdliRqVOyzg4WJe0UmoLBJqtctkfsP0VHojyS8vQQgB@St9BCrXk9x2kbe9/@I33P/rH73/4m@9/@Cs4Wku5cnovLam3LI9BwPwHhMOAhQ8JhwE/g/TbKZp6k1KfgW3js3wpa9t29bPPPhPaFwqeU929YJ/Bj30WXIx74TlW3yvwQ3c82MrAvfHqVQvXVCNuisqBKxp/@1645R1SkrQ7qR1F1biXcaFs8lisCg7ZUrYZybrS729V4MfgUalsnaelnSYwfRT1UjCCIqk@1A2FqXo6u5XVIaCS4@FYxd7N5FLFLV0HETiFcFPE82wFPFg@y2YpP8kZ4@tL6A6BZltknOGTXNF7JuCD/kXGSizLmM3/VYGlaNKZL32kFkYy@PH8JLhRyEMyqVm4qkVMIeNc2RZ3oQVrSjdXZliC2Sw1A2kbDJBCCrzuAd9fq6UwYo1nEay8MPUSo6ykUjUoN8bmcdLtEoKY3SMoELOWesbaW7UZj5hCePUAHSkBnZ6JqiamSrX7kGBtdp8hLAROYF@9qtVLtVkdwb3j2EnNUvcoTwislprV34G9RjAhnhC7/w6yUqqlUvUSJoiF5NWTbvNKylPhqOwplvLrAN547mBnl7E7oloS@WrFBiKMh8ZnahEaA0Jw8G@mtvzi0D8w0r1FCN@gpPxUGPffIZ54h7PJGADgSpIsywxu3Aiww3bBe8ZBpShZeKU4hBS1CGoBoQPDiaiUkKL6TZEF0o/Vtr70hcCwMJubm0KsLmbFI5lQpyjMPanQIQzcl4hyTIWJhbKIzgadSAnyAvGrlP5mHFf44owDZndS/N7d3WJ3oJj0XrgJTEplnZwT41C2UylRA/h1JyW8BPlHgHZKgC4EeVajFcWUkE4zJtdi6MeOjo78TJDDy5qQgmauZVW047rWdDqNQQxZTsvptP@W6U0Osm@Qydd/y5uIXPpoPNO0XBXEtCpDJxaVqVSQtdHx3bt3UCu00atyCFIu8/d8abkSeYIDVxNkWfPg6JKWKwt8CoCphRxjCZrthSvJ8IxOAhpSUuAHBHg2gisR10qlOIUE/MuJrWATYEGlBoGTvbE6ZjW4uPRZyicDz/0jtn/0@PHBk@Nxq8UE/AjodGK0x67TNTwvgX57T@7zwyFauZCMNRoI@riiIYkRDioZTCh1eP/Z4fMK48X2KyFBGavSEq9f0LIqxMbjT7dj/iYoEb/k6IjP8VlZlC2hlYH8JWN1IdY1UKbBtXuUtausKjz2BvecGUtk0qKYVgsoUyZxpRLy8YvOlKGeYa6UCHoVHhmRt7cJA0L9XKJ1FDRCfRWEet3fPshUof784BgiHB8xVcvIQv0zNpMxQelSqFs1y7AHk@Em7sMTmxkxUqbNRiaNPy2bhaeaK6TVfLG1sWGdS5hmk6rtHDdUXoL1XMJifBUuJnxVYF8FJ7ggDdwlyfwtqodHVX@fIGr0S/DNgqKah46WFHBWnYMTxtGrCu17eVVKiG18/vmE1esgykuHD4QY0IshC7bKSWZPHspUzb2pa5DvgLGe@YmJn@iUe6Y3tvQ5dB7ARuzy8rIPkA4fMK2ukZXH6OHzsksuHTBfznQhZlcqtXdqrihoJ5XKu6ymCeAgbCm4F28DGgBtadhS@K/qQSLZbEkBWqWKIryy2ayA09SCUDEERttW3mVqNYm3wWxOpV0rAn71RZ/VtPDyw87uLMJmMzws@oAHG0xclgn8itzPtxUEsgHScKMefWO86nfPzN27WZwvyeYy4cQIlZhdQt1sZnNZxDgehGrFckV/xUYUxVZMsIwJ69XAHGvCg8/9aWpMZGhDspEtZYRYI9YQ/v9@@YtS2@N6NqNuK2Mw6mDMbSs6GDtgzG8rHTCaYCxvKyYYp/WsmtlWpnWBCdtcGTBDXUM1cWLMUPc4dxPrnmH1ZTwfVRMpAU3c9pXr14OI9V6t53SnuDWl2pNN2zZc1AzAI@RyYtWxUU1lDRXWkC4FlkieC4PaGekvEIzaQEbNR66tW0JP7ji9uexN5haeNLIctxYHTjUeeCygG8DC4PzcTjabqzRYSx474x1ByxdTDTUDYw/eaimtpTeMnWKx0pO7lqG7O/lKvpTu4SEmf6VuJ5@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@Gv4hFhZTThG3U1PYLwFHsFmj1AHzMRhxw5@BWzA7hndNSH2hzrtyt53Hc/7e4S5p9sn3Ou@yRUmh14PdfwUojcyJ8M1IV6MR6j2yXD/wSAcjDqQQSSHPMA9eLiW46wKUGQvnq4p5ePwEwWADP6NAgj@7PCjh8eR9/HB3v5DocDuHT25f@WV9wPl2aODB8ehtch9g6j5EMQvHjx6dNXqv3JHL571p46Lt/Dg6EVu8Qid8NCvkINrOVDoTED8B1qJIwVWBGS4fDEwqAIeFbkLcvVd35gvLIwZNH7KTzSbXnh0gR9urwjHwTFnnSGl7Risy7V7oaBPmjd9IUAtlgVhzGznjBUzrOdYlu4yp9/fAMehjkc2DeSELQtbIiZ95rhW78zsGRvCYzwdWlYhOGVCeAhARtMuKY4ALgj1OMOoZjNcOutYU4NNx2ytI7zQCY2uORjCGHzmBAGEjq4zuL/sBfGN6DW52WHC0yC3az7W9eBCTNiNlfKiuC@KD/WJXnWN4suql6lU1Hj8qSuWxTGMyro3MA5m0HDZC@hIujtPixNZfMDkdmyA6zGWM0b5xRs3gOEva43WTu6iXsrks3/9Wz/@uz/59UGNppCamf0Mzilt7zx@5EzYO2QoKl7OmeusVLF3mpxHpE3@FaCBwCczYoV9dlkmwUkrl/KlclYrpUvlUi6vFvL5tKqlQeoslkHsyKgltVDKl9V0KVcGdiVXBt98uegz20rAXStbFQBrd/Hj79ske8lDELL4mip7m9CTLKaH9ikTDYgjCijoTuic/JZZg5GWqRmWLTKAqLMuiz14sJ958EAU76EF96TsZ0Sxh5Z8KZMp3hNFg3z2S8h6iQ6PU0I1muKEWzKZe1AVUw4Av0AhikO0HBRwqlAUTbTs7z14gOn00aJhfAh2wn24xQosRQhmowVkAALwJoQGwfZ4OjnK6AFaMEn0ecB99sFPFD8KsoM@z3gwDuBhUNK9PVE85Ja9PfTZp2LneUa/hpY9ukTRBQv0EVEcgGHgQu8UxQ4YsaeIYhdM3bkObiMw4UcK7IkuinOOHkSQKM4otN49EcV24I7JfOLnJo/YrZBF5aXeJUsZf6KoBZnGYNnQkhXFXGjJQdkePvxEH056xoBfc5e/u1DShw@zujmbHjzofPRRZzDouPO9g4@eodf@/kNgW@ZTtzPo@BE7bbgciLX/UNNPRvOrF5T6sN2u6NZKr6@12zndvuLVnrcNzCHEegM5868BJjRq74PX/sP2rr5qTZwAtpFIjODdweveCN739A73Ci7yoves0xGr2PwVpZkQULDAxW3sjidAdO30SO@6ThXtsxrLpLEHzxuFTKtKHmwEAkKmeon@/QQ@dZxfSp7PG7NaplWb1Yoa31TVT4jNmZY3xfTGaEct5ysb@o6q5VKzCqrqcPpxFpfUHZZQ7269ZYknyR0NhAWxubMjiQ21taOppUqh@HJrKorJCj53ssXK20QmnmEMH8lGsbVTzEdiFIspXdEqxSKwbICTCYz8HZz0aScSZ4Z@kkxibmkKAopAZWVzKqdZ7Sdm6VmN54vNk9VZTa1y5dwscw1YD78EMe1OHJeDHAC42U6mghspEqJaLomQAUVJJJMh0VPAtNjx@unXj0@Ojz8j3rDuz448dQ2kXlXf@tHDffnwKLDhNxzkB8iyOq68j1RryYfzroHTMQgr8kMYbUHwC9zwSKTrWPIB7RQEvjfwCNRIyb4@Zfn44RKc50PnjKeMGiWqpJTT7hoMP3Fh9pheq4NJ77EE5YrpyTMa59v1eq1dG5HSBShiEOtrjL7/sABz6PG8h3ouKPo5HhP0Pdq1zGW1U5vFZgCnXWOS@mrk9F5pqW61h1@2uFe7h5GrbXh3qkbNcF3HFUHsFqv9Hbs2tT29bzw1XNTgcni0CVwHnh1M9JmR3GTNAwy9jyLNpVR3mb3I2ZPpKKFL9U5y2Qln/kIHRE7i60Ghz@k4a7smipfVfo0lXkLQN2B3N1miJ99L7uSqgKd7rJ0Ep8yr/qs@01ghVyWRJIGwoCsRfrDcOkvW6l@DF4d9UqlAbvyKPgGomBgANnvkAaHH5mW1W7NYQmIzliQk5aqDWgOjX@BjWxLFliQ1LlpCXZI@FerQX6vzmF7zph36KBLLdFQtU6jOwE0t5qpDqF795azq1sZT16haYPUnDPnJXb0KSAXcAZi3F4n3v/SN5LaUr3G3KoG6QCagLbdrs6qNalahYdSyNfBINXKZNAj78CimYczXCmm1kM6mc2mpiK4w4KfzaXAEYQiYkISVEBkT05lZRlbTqqGmE5lXZu9VMn2SAOaGkMaS6YlzYE9HDFygqrBtkhXegJ6UtmWBkNZzmL4tUWMFklHFggHWh2xspocI6pmhWxQjmZRYdithbSYwzObxdHzQaFUqB7Px18ErIb3ZKaSKmdTbZLKa2EjWPOONUK8KdSQvVOrxBrRcfy6VedNRA2oZTGpRqzQaHSxiMZPOZrJQOrN9MdgW62IrndkoqFBFl4zIBuN0Izq9iBzPwm3cRibdMqDq1LJWFWSa68uWNKms5LfyGT7fyGMKY5@8ISZZoikGp9QT8XhRi8eT8SqudWyI/tQ20DSiZ3GgrvG76o4IzJhYEcsaBliQRjqInAlyB@zYpYCcI8uBDHwuXJ5fbteFrwjP8XjptvYSf8WXj/eO8PcVcCqDtfTy8YujF0cPBKbQvlVgQ6sbVbnaroJFkuu7QqzCGFDSpq9CS9lg7MvuiE1t11/ydxPPTABcgVSnN1iLdqoZJgp47BNUz7DD4lAG3R01NC3bamhFGPuAmgZBNU2tolKqGJ7JkOsKHb7LFbN0@E6Izc4hs9spcv8am8/1lBRMEdxlu4PUJj9MVBa3MV7Bj8cX5jYx0mn7NMZw3/3L6mn1JFPeFgi5sSsb9Kt7tb3Bs70qE7PFoljd22@DUUywWFXM@0CruYfxZ/Hj@GF8O1kXSwVyLe/ilPrqOYw6cFcnJ6p/4KmYaYvVGGuLef9kYeRUVE7cLjcF3M8fj53HWSx@Cb9FFl@@DQ5NFQDGSWb7JdDDWJidZCxIQmuLL5lXPZHUzDY0mV06Oarxk6MsFp4dxUVzfykpmyuwZDlY5/lKfDcWx@WUiue9WxxK9KGrbbEeYyCtnFRj20wsBXh5mzmpisWCbyuLOb@AST8JEEGxRQdn@r72SoPOFLOdwAHETpwShME@n8fVi5jyaux9rpWyjw@P7Pvug8jpspeYAcgBHpWrVl62N05U6ERZMXuSjrHdGB2wEMuQvsYdAOEnTK2@RMQz8cX9o8diDpEFEhw4JaBQPNeQaHPjYsPB5SoW7td8Z3/8dcbG8WwO9zvWYrNazj8roNbrkrqtoSa/IqvAkNlXC1Lmos6JQp08Chr4vP@lH@Rm2yWwaxkV7JqWT2n1urqlsWRs/P6L30edTOcHn@w9YnFc5Pi7P/mRVvy7P/lXtAMxfkkLH1q2GIOQaFQLxdj5@fj8/BIu7pePtWLXNl60oDIVVS8Xt2QojVLSwdBWYrxCgEksqsmYJ8X8baaFvJRIqIqW3MqWMknwufB1riW0TAmswdofOYmFvJiMHTwz85q6u70DJdvJ5rTqBrQ0NTyjzMLftuGVY0Ks9PjVBWNg6dZ7g4GpkUlRWOWdxLbfSdvsHS67vZM22KtaHTeOqHiyOViW2sKTnrg4G6@nlK04A@GS1RuX1ctWita1QFp/aRhbdvMKHpobeNhn2WnLhp@x5dEPIwUOHlgDm7H12hMTW0lF6fXE6z1722D5OjSVLWVx/pptBatV/CdJzeT7X/oNTSv83Z/82kX7ov2ZBgJ6uVxQtdjPfrY9taee0av/DADcoIknELKJz0aVOWgIhXPG1daafqzQIHdFITa1URDh4QNRHYVzBkycObCNHonqwikynlSzba4MspegYFuoqCNNggwpX0tWBSHg@Lmg4g66aYLBtlDXcqOVFM6Fr6IX8DUMhJ2q8NUFKHAYASfjdNueNXXHdFgqQfHUVprdhSiQwldR0eYGKRjxB0VJrTJl63pUnmWPsEZMKhsZnodqO2E8F74KUXyF9NacjXXUhYMhTRtGYRmDUD7Jo9eAtFuQtsUjtMk1QaXnAdKM545HskGYEb4KfBlhwQR2jZnbEKAKlOurgAAoQ8IHbLbYNssm2bmZSlUXOkEv8dAGKknVAz0cAkZDaD3U@xJErmI4cAIhCj@BjO3Cr2HgliOOARAOg2@9qIEYhtHJhhwwKcr5YFAAi5TSJaho7O7dRa5qNbOXZFQihH9ijnG2kerBXp1XABaIsHd6FTHNUNtqNXANmx1gPEXZhVYncTWr1UhUJqL1UhDg/8GNFlvklaoijyoWwK8v3iu6gDKIjGjnddhl2zWmasUkCzPfhbx3KVOkDSGUy5uzO7L2WeB5CTn8WSz4wBgQrePoDK7fbq8qYmEgtUzx606ojo8TA1@BCle4h8TvcBLEDmNBUUyLQvdNFyRG2hMS6PpMZNUkRlvoRqV80LEKLcfwdEM@iS@KhaEZvHXUWemns0G6troOVKg3dmxScklKuPBoCbQIoFG@fkCe7al9hl8D9OuGIkdz5JFuQGz5mGNS2umgNiOKi1syOq6hnwS4STNjILPuqMe0MktQQyM9hnYILkmRKMMdEDwQxx3LGEGWnhsGHVn0KooyAGZ02iFljo9NaFfDByaMQLan3OcIVs7ME1M5RrXcktPHk41cNU4M@Vfsfnz3h6840XKcE2aZJwafmE8sKRbyGIheID2kAbOLGxBbwY1FWjaNM0BqmoeCuwivIjeW0pG4G4l58vo7q24k2lijFzTemFArlnGq2xH80nUh@HMO3twLVJORgi2wyyHJNXylRLU4qhsJtW0JvpK1Gun3knHBZ5wQY2KgnAyNwtg1ThnOHgg4xgDR7AZqfrAXQ2m/SgMA9T3oWaizdOJWUDkV5MTtJbrQ9XwCb7M7LKsJGJBrjvO1vAEMrPraMnTwg6hYDm/Sg4qRaZUD6Qr0zlEP/FAtit/8MH7QutFM@mQXzZtt@OBw0KG0aox3i8CSj1iwd2B7pqJvgGcBcrgiJxsJMQVgU2JS5KDD@Fej89YuEC2psOuQ0gwh@KgGKMQq6EhyUCll5LN9Anjc0z3@bRdfo@nZ2ZlMananrikbHn7KznNs3VLGAxOYbkeZGKOx/9Fws6uMA7gLk8S/YCmPh@OdGfK1tfLdOX8LQt@r@ZuzEvG@F8fB8RS/1DYYkUo@1IXnUYN6YNJXHrsJf68Yb39aK30etL8Ktj@pFL9EICCvAZhZep7upgFYutM9SffPelXf45Q6JACHWjQCR1R@7QaWkReYzHE/DOFMkI6GXh3rhJbNAZLIp8oXSfMSBiHngdW3j80ZRLKNM7bnuvo8Qf5JDI0NODEntofNYdgnHzCi3vtzronZnDXmraXoszA6DGrhphEX9e0J5zcD5Wq50X/G/WfgP@P@s0WiQbKNWYuzZOh0icXBVo9qWoOQCGYehLnkKqwXPgQZ@HEQpsgNQ86X3C7h7tYodoBvboN6rAUNA9rEGBBuJJTGy2aj2bI942yrlVIG0NhFQgTUOIButAinZ73QjNi3Tq2x4y052aidF0YlP9/o1B36rYG3FSxjWEHUMDi@TFSoOhj5u1s4Q@AXGCAgHwaeyBrsTRJmshrqgSdPaDgNcYFjnrGGn5kWcV@@l@8G7BJHPUdsFFArAgjdwyJBNsGHBT2Hf7g0oA6fug6ECcJK9K3FESr2i7figMkrXYXTmipVUiRXkhRkE9CO7GrtalECf6iKxhWvSDEv/fqPZn/jS2e/D/1ide6pwfIBoypEuwruRAUWwu8uhFVWr0XqFXKgbOmW4cLIdcD5U3@0hmS2lEDM4OlgEbwzc9IdJiKV303y@qGjtaItVsKmMK/VoIjzGu@WvF8EKOUID6N5frR50BD8@JyAAIzMymiGH20WjTar1TjhYLM10c4imZxRJmc8Cg89W5PJlh8NpKfDYHjB6mkBd4pbZUWAp/JhFNigscg8/dTAPQivUekoLs/4aS5oDrUCvw0hi43trNtamXojkukI0boCABviNQA9/g30inCV4KlSaAtpFEdlQKO4zW8GnFZAAyMSXOWKuRNhIyMZGBh@MUXjAPRdMdUQRJWm2PGX4beYDhyDW73umFkOqS47ZtJXfv8gji3EbKSDRrgPNZNDgoySzAvb12gb5TlibG8KAg5wdZ0zhyVWMNvgrkz9qErHcjrKSMe9RPhlZO4qj@fJQH7ARSq2O3Ym@sTJ5SpcaDKp2a1Kn8sM5sB28INqEeX8wOv1HMOz4xOo1K4zsE3PSDPUm3pi@GKH4X@dRIjyyb7R8QTB39XGxVgEzdsVsrrttmmbk3Y7gZtFk/9vd9@33jaO7HltPQUiO20yoSjJiZ1EjtyRbTnRdGLn2E4yWcetpiXKZkeW1KL8R51kvnPOxb7A7v0@wr7KeYdztU8xW78qgAQlWXa6Z3f223zdFkkAhUKhUCgAhapKYjLPtqNgz@XlHNa/9GSVJ/Gkge4NnP7Jr2Fr5N4OE5EmdLHDqPXZ2RvoRPgTqSmSYS3S/yn1jDQYFffTlSN7sYcqfTJyOCLLWf@8f0pa30XsY5c5NwG@kcIGQsFgwLh4KsCStmLFG@FR4rS8wNVFf/ruouqnFSdwk/IrWQAZYnhqOEljUHY4o7rmjdVJMVPfwffje2DjezAfX16FT@IsS/OqJH5f1Y@cFAJlTNF4dDsaaDrJrfYUOhlUks/Qq6TAnVFss61eG5jWKGtNZ/c7xB9e8hbTW4L4@5voP78DTfH6XbsvoGGvDsYkb85h9upwDMzYnDU7lL3hQvZMV5ew9vYd66K8CD@8AxWC1FgWXD044KaBiYBFcbKBbADfwvMwj5vie7aZq0riDJyGl576vHJzF20322E3GIdtR@f0LLimxfu0YGN5dbeGQ9Cx0OvLWs@huctNUmkaB9ElU@UGlgm8S9e9ma0kS5RwD@@UM4aNm@mH9CnRjC2@quxW0zpgeXkR27GXEbY/B@PBWGI8dCUAopajMv9IT8I9yO0EITrI7Fn20mrdeeJz30madIcZIcnrZ5sMF@wGIhxzTffh95Ho9pZS51qFqqaXc9noRrN7PJrX4xZXGJ6UY6e7seRtTHdnnrNYTYClImzr@6aQKcgwkGm1HBuifJnbY/3elEzAN96n690wqzRnCNSkJEu6UcTLbdYv3BxWxg36xYbTe/oFwNNw1BSGMm3DnpaOKaw45TwYWFqL/kJKOkGxqCgk12hYuXLmmbJ/@ZbU2bqxztZUna1MnckIyFZpZcq1MlXqXkD3zOuCbtgZ3SCdkYS1M/3ME9v0r9cPhtit@LIcLVciTy1fLldIIC@Hy5W6Q0J5ub1c2eaHeLlywA@flys/0UM6tpa/LlfMsECGIb3ywwt81yIc763lypbjfsuNgs9hbOr1lytJn1KeH@WVKUKkQLtJa8QRW6@vmzkahjSxsVLpKXBM7GH5xPswHv9fov8kXhlHMkIi9jgfcGb1UJUzk4Y1Y0g9NG2YSBkzRnJFz@b1vR02MEuyoJqHtMazyzB4UsMXl7PCSBBDKp9o0C8hCLlZmY2RsmayO6KjaycO5U7O1s/U81kfaDucfkSZj9NKOEidLm/6KwtCOvBueKLwTXhOoWOqY4xwJuvOQAtE/WV5TqPQ11lcdO/bPcR73dlMhG3BZJFeYrCWTCcdjg/nUNmgP8gyCafixkNkl@FNORmU4N6JYiwV9Mi8IZk/65ZBMNiD353XHKscUMuIICQelY5llCXzAstiJKWyztJUZfARCpbMoREetj5zAMBt/cj5RNx4PFfcNA2ZslIlS66smKTCPtydXQQjqT1ZvNbhBO37lq@m5DX2WhwAsEomtYh87X@H/t4X/d0o1IYIExXMUqxnT6XT6vXcWXYC825a7XQHItFT2@5M5SipISU5rQ4szXwer02p@DD5ECVfKk2gT2j7hmzJmuAWuk2uLQQWtIThZfbj5xX6@HnlZkJNayTdS98oLT5q0nCk4QmmadPm4yoNn9XFSOH97aD73R08zHaw3XmAxw0YTpBcRvnwosdWLunYJrEtXyBSyxUlgpyPS5NuTj@SuOej2@TYlj7sNfe393Zff6RJ98mTJ66eo8cpfhi12GtN5nGBzNbqyXwwY9my4iFKFw67sR0fn/WHo3ufevkpWSLCmpSBgGox7KfHuKtlmSXPJ8YulZO8FkU1rM/pMAgyUgmqToApO9J0HRFBwpHzINBAjHpL9PZ4teZyPKpmsxech80mT18mHrqexdA15kTc/fviveJFPOS43xJM7SqXY3cgantPfXhVO1SHr@pq593WT@rj3jv1obZ7CD8Qb99tvm5sKfq/vntQV7mMKR4CT2JBSXTdDlshwgmrlVLpsWLIW/3BWOSOs@XK94PgXL3qt0IcUz2Pg/MXZ/Li98LRhpSq03J0jD3MiAONnkcj2FtwZExaxkK5afMtTVyvUJT3hNa051jznvfbUSeivDmsfQdRGJuLfaobUQ@SvDV32z1RkhAEk02HOLgtLLCuqHhA@XF2Q2ACsb8CiZFDoma2faUJl/z7bgoe1vffHCi4FNna291uHDb2dg/Uzt4@vb792Nh9SfRsHBzuNzbfIYkzvtnbbuw0tmr8QRAo@Qq@Pn69iEdzUfCRnanS@oyTb39A3Z@8ZXe9ocGrq4Dvq8Zq@aIH6RMF3ej3sL28nruIob7gjiwfFShnqbb/8j3N@Sr8DSec5iiY7Q/y72IOzLpUUs@5NhosGzTe1vVwpWmvUHb5POJ8rBCbKVxnHyAOP3vKAGcjnnYUqvwWbFSw9y2uQngsG9BU0T2CDVDGYKWqOKba8rL3nEFuUG2tbh8uZKU2MSLULyj6wpiarOeYYtpWBkBxgaTRw35QeT35QHxPH1Z0taOhZFCPkg@SQT2WD1BFG7AdUas6x8Vo7wLiWa3Jh1/PBzt8LKyeJB82A17FPtU4Sb9xlwYqiUkJxyldjpwnuzwc3TeIW1HERWLOj6hy3a4MjFDimZJMlKNEtm2jnHkSNh0cNWizN4kTjlTiBtgJBZ1RrJyq66tDGAeFvUhiFp52g56YQKWmO8x76im8VFX1dfgoifXHV3IGfWZAxBnN4pGU29ZaYXjXclRyc6rGQNtIcrxdY4J2GwKbUwj8ETAEqJBZ6bR4puIrxADT72hWduI@cST2bf9m5yd2bl@0wkwBbbXl/Br9/ruriexl1knGTpGxoy76PRySWslHmZ3@kMY4i1WOjgYp2DrrD0aR9KGTbQGfOPE0R7kxsVFtv1Q3MrWBDpM19vo9q9IT4uIbaj0hprxLrczxcnaeiK80bDZxPk3CYncHdIKT/mVonZ15OES6CrH9Qoown5Vj83M8YkxE/8ylsuNvCtF2n1Y3tjc/Ff72i4eQuyIWJOK1MTrE/8SYqIuGB5/zscHiEHqXHmkmVGJ8cYLS2gZPS0uMcgOM1oFnEa3rXjTXkzQxN57@jutKk9/549evVSlVgGTSYdLjMyeVbp46MlV6XOZYaRMQS3YSsiTrHfPFY5iJvH6BK0roBThd6kGOYN0@EYhQixDTupOLDkkWHQ9ad3cC31UbbFFhFEnxk2H3R/FnZ7P6cMMtpgYlyiKnY0S0ZyCXXdcyS@H5agrc9nxwJL/vDu7pXOxkevguaNtzoX0XboWHN8OSacmCdXewf5sDVia3PwSW2u7dDFgmyWloCacnzOktLSbWtPNr/GWq73jsERjMvdhBSYBatV30@IjaOGR3pIBrg0kVooPD7fr@vsrL@oTKktzDkqGtxSBg31NvU2vbqMfCzk@UpmSxnChP5kvGos38mzeYZxLvBlGhdRBP0yMRFqnb9050LVJPzyysQrD1PQtEQ7ksdl@MDIqPNOBvtAYkZNNOsxqYm9nMRZl8otg2Atd080Q3tm342cJa5m5EWR6ObUC2TVBwipsls/vvg@jHFVOPKFhwOIUGt0mTpvmG1gkHVPGAMvp@tgfndIvpUhjZi4K9aGgHw69SVsP@8wzFjCRKuOjClljXyrFGTfTjJaPmsEEipoEAlp46USyaKcGIeP7y3O5QN530nOwUREom4u6@sLmCih9/01MYUyOZJ6uJQm6PtSXG5shgeYzdWQ17/eZM92ELvTYpHiarImk7t6rCP6YqmSUyNRmaz2yMSSTIa6urj26DPdkKU7zwZ2HLHDIpP0fnA1rfpyDjcczb@8S5jV3PpKcMMId0YlpvBsxEQVJ1ZswpmbbzZGTjR7jIvhAhg6AGCGU8Waurridwmw1dZiQbOmeZaoM1hJOGyqiZov63@dVBIN9a373vr08GGzLBdPAbrPLf9IdxmN7Ks3zmWJ/gayD7LRwOe5xN7jOdA4rD15jmXrbj23Zi8CqtQiKft9kt6ejbSWJ265m9Bq6Etxd9RC/H7t765PZeobxuN3Wn8bquHrCr0U5mLzI/zLuW7LkX9eYhwDKY9yUwffAdvvtxhf4nHDwDksjEt/kcpo17K25MEdKajzjMlTYL1bK1PNn7nbgV9OBlxcvfj1Xe@4EK8i5sfW/HnbWzXlrPlCfk4kHPoVJevuDnuSh9w4YuIGVBSG/iuzVh4aaGsZTE9ZrTPuyjcLAVXsvuGVtOBsXy09Lasxy3rueNvPOjZ8feg1Y1r2jyDXrn8cXwqv35tH922VFdNfj15Lo1/v03pVYfwyO4WvlBPD6X16pFdrH7RMFZ@LMSc65G8Ee@JI9o2r6EGVZqWaXr8PV7yuUHXjRXcENigkvVg3PDhbhiN6qeH60dV3vV0vr5Ue94HZf8Rg@ro4flhw4@/ECzKMkYOZk/Gh1jTrV3XcPepYJXVQ5nq6@GKL4aQl/eBMOo/7q2@zKzGwcFAFtg2tabN9QlcvkCrNlw98TvhVeO3ibzFDg2BwUpt8C3gspwBsD7ydiOaUeEGfWKR9psfM1/x25uoeRfDEZ9TjGuMMFa6mv0NbdgrjGVeEeBshxFxmEm7hcQnDSPg4Mh@ToWK@pCWdS1Mu5OuhaII5RkcZj/lM/jTiEQ1Xe5jo5zsR8GrTMg0SW1@isXU8@fK7wRq8U@7@LBlCMY8oWJ0jEecQBCPwM@bUAVrLnHfO0jR83HexkP8oX3qEZ8T4YN5HOsKSIF5t/qC99v4vLPiQBC@AXRuXy9xak1L1Ik5e4gby7Az1x24Y9jBlyrlE5ZQGMBW@qrpsDZUpxphGo1mej7whXIKbSif7oFhTK/TTUjye9KdiYJn1Prtxi05C7lpA38dNNijlWsYIqZzBYpFm6lBna6aHn0JqRhNVZbYbdLSAstFlJy4JHv9@r6Hyb1x0eo8zhBXtILU@mFTLov6YJUmsunCT7NVLEz5Re/pPm@qXyazZuqq6pYefGpp1s@qSRp3vV5eWN/1G9GaeaNpCuFK5OE55mEgpXy84zel5R7mTIJgyfpR5Ku@XtF93yCZSbvi2z9@M3pDgrZeFbbmkxwqd@Luj/mdJR3nQI2yxM1lZLiHL9TmUFV1XcwtTghDQ77/DxsN6oplIdlI3F4zOQ3nr/I@1rJ@NGZRENuMU4NrBljxKIS1/mQCXfNFxapHk6@Z4FgmGA0ZUbuhik81oXHFljkumeqlVuQUwOcmjY5xKu4F/kVf8xgzyJn8i3OTlwQzK@l8XK7OUsgFrr38rPJlJUmuC4iH3Wj5swiad3jSYizhcSutQuc1BnKHewOtsHvJXLCFhRGUkzRPUnRlE4zlA373tSFSPyW@3vxQe5lQDr2oBteqxqWGQHfwsplLriPwngUw88WuwCKLwaDLk4dWeG74ivUOojByiqOW1KI1szu5xqw7JH8Hp70hXQq5Ks9QL6CgUiaEF@cnuIyGW7A9q8gWrHjEo38XK03lg0NGjOPVuSaeajgfIMFcDc6tZGQnpPRA0rHg6AV@jnS0WLSfnLS1E6kw97yfjrujcCdG01plVzuXy6i1uetlzjPfVIuPSpbJLvUx8El/9Hj9IIVEckkrMAj42r5cS5nnQ235Gy4AICeeo2J/j3xZngZ9nphrkYzBmeMSWmNw@Fl2PZzuf0wOQQGXLAyTiZxD7t/MWzJ5g4pXQExI24Jx54chxGH4RfzsxwXt/iszMvh0Co9baauvozaIKC5cdLp43SYDyzgJkDogULn4YiI8sBVWZT47FnjwrrLOTaiiBrwc2KdTSRk6PVHUYt6hneycl0CJccgaWW99gQmVF@rG@BysD8LAVyPSSlgEDBHSfNwyOlD8@/CQemGmTP2wPRMkaRfn8cKDfdwGJH0TQnMvcLFLNypgw9fNQ7Uwd7O4Yfafl3R89v9vfeN7fq22vzIZ9w4KGcnyOrV3muSLslpupya79GHfO2ASuY5IVfb/ajqf327Xz84UHv7qvHm7esGQSPw@7Xdw0b9wFON3a3X77b59J0gqN29Q/W68aZxSNkO9zyu1RTLpeXU3o56U9/fekWvtc3G68bhR65xp3G4i8pwql9Tb2v7h42td69r@@rtu/23ewd1hYblthsHW69rjTf1bZ/qpzpV/X1991AdvKq9fj3R0L0Pu/V9xUYCVis364RlbZOWsKiJ27nd2K9vHaJB6dMWEY8QfO2pg7f1rQYe6n@tU3Nq@x89DfSg/i/vKBMlqu3am9pLalzOuYUq1C9b7/brcJ8EShy82zw4bBy@O6yrl3t720zrg/r@@8ZW/WBd5V7vHTDB3h3UPYWIm1w1wSBqUTo9b747aDDdGruHNGe8ewt7B5c6@QMRhrCsUdFtJjDMINBaItLe/kdABR24Azz14VWdvu@DpkytGqgAi4qtQzsbVUhEPLSbqXbrL183XtZ3t@pI3gOYD42Duksd1jhAhgYMMj4S61Cl77jV6CfCSx6JWXOGcz3uTtXYUbXt9w1grnMTBxw0NLcw2bZeaZr78H1sbaJEfewZBOf2xkpn@tNlCG@f0zsys/doEo9JW3vbdZqRtbOrfJrwjmadpxOulOw0mmmSRHrNuKxphycXp82o1@njjmlSTDY@zuNTD@GdXETG@ZSbE11N769wgcXFZvN9rUkL3YNm0/XuUjKDxm0l9Db4vFyubiMCYGDljY2fSkXo/jxDqI0f9EEnG@rhAAI5hfo/iOlbcB66qlhsh7oYLu8DsNk6iuXY5AxHKSQa@bIjQvqkVfLOBL9Hmh24oGPA@60m9klhGcmZ@jH96X1NX2RysD6QdJbtrmIRi1hGI/o9NNVIJewSgf9ojwRRh6v04zD8fOqU7Oqw5vdP@/2247qmDOcd0Trw1HFvKX4Snk4UL0yWZ2T52FnHjojNuptVmOT8WZNM6X7xh9wyB3@aI/5xDTbi8wG7plwVb1brTUvnBykOiyRPadcWuF7BnQyd703tr40PWM2VVh6vT3x/lXyXsQV7QfgFpgnviMsd88@rY8lAA4x9cRBJIu0ho1i0yhh7kyTzFWU8Q6arqA3LH5qrz0Ke14kkpMheBF27TszGw@jaxp7k8Mv92pvNdzs7JDqB7eOnq0/W1nOJ262/evL7EfWw6172OjageZz0NE6yRskWKT48UizP6Sn7MwMXi8gI5/mm0/gj/DwkdhtZSyYIMjQ3RnyrHkz08iHokFfsgONezvDrzJGpGcDJNNVFa86Da1bxA9KVmAe0MUt3zL12jT@AnQx/M8STBmkG0izGzoyJc2l1wXIvv2NMRXlxw457kMXPGz4WN24JDXiri@1ncbuW3zRvW70Yiykjxit3O5ckJO5NYqGMXUVPRvZb9jOiN4DZexh9@avmN3r8qB3csbu7IB7VRgdExp2kJPap081o3egjDfkYwUzgVM3U9Fxhl9/VSPHY09vJiWMQazQwKojMAxvfLOD1xI/IZJVsAfti2VVfhFPhvANw1jXH6nfi3FnN0VDWjf8Q/W68UiiBlTg5EapdJXXkTJaPiR8LQ84Mmf4UPRj@P5EmM@A/pxUnQU@pZTkBvBMlGarQipavTJToyhw0WKcbKTXtTx9TMN/sjjlLGqZPb67lfg2RQPfO2Hz4yG4PO84MAoDJsbFhj9/EJO0soKXTi7yri@OcpNc6HzhKzxVmqpiCW1g79ljt8szZCl5c5cpek1XhayqqXsjC7YRHPS2ZJpby6n6cF3Cu8f9RfMAbIMmAZy49E6vVSc4q6VFm5IB2tWRNOO3EYxKppd9uPLV7oCwXmRnZr0@@DKEI9AbwmW4nR3XpKzHPzXpc5JlYHbIXPDhoxzIZk492WXfChpjdEHDut3kzBIFfRleYILoCnV31pdCUc58NRVBJanWY@hmEuHV9Ii1Pq1cJ9rwzCQ5NsH/Xk9gAoexqmRy@OPjQGNrX5X31JhgTyt27NVtYrPjgoO/BdhGVybaELo8gN61@f0iqY4B2E45eNHZ99UFvOoS9@GKo/RfSfBYN9Y6EUfqpGqhNsnrnaUac8jNqcTTCbYW2z/zBTToPYSEq7kmuC2vKIeY1PLphNh2j64dl5TxPU54TTdgtKRPxuVpTX79KLiGodhkaMgWjOFlcsM0m14Nzh2T4XfWHnzH3QwXqtcN24pnUAsl7gdJJjR77eGyNpOmDfsw7GtQV2AFJKFGWjbTEUJXm6CeanbRdUz71jgnfpdyS768nYVJjLUUVpYyrayfmWytQZ4JKK9o1aOIstLyyyqjMWnB9u3Exxt5Cs8fWKv@pl4iUiigR1ftGdcSTyM3k6SOe9CZ/9X6M0UNfcMatVVAgDJ0V56rTco7xg03Bhygctu09UdJk2sEA22@89On3mBfN1qF2@9cKRnE4phVAqxhdFxlG0/lL/6zX3Op3g9OoHwW0ToNH/WuReHgc8yM67HTYv4o5fpMEpbQytcfps/iXETdseE/OJdct11zxKBw4tpnCaDiunYmbCN45hxFgGnSW@Xsw6SMtKfN4NS2Uy94/ZXu8srt@Y9lH5VmF5UQfALSA25iwoJA7pCO@mGRdPl2fynAyL4OF44kqqMC9wWIvg/EzIhEfw2QwNshMmSXYjcDK7EaMj9rXXpt9EA7haCncDhFiKHb4sxcgkjdJkR9hKVBR5aclq6icolzDDyEexjeTe@XJPxl7QuBPoF9@NItbZjECi7iO8bYUy3pFexklXNg8MGIZzZKYpFh0GvWs64ccz@N6Emo2eXwTNdjyh5Qi7WZviisxIh1a@CDMoNMkkdMcu5hUltWyy347oILURk7pZoYNb7Of5cGPQ1zZOYNg2tKQHQvpm0jVIiohUvKEea2NsvhUvn3ErKzctdcmCFidZXJmxex28kZz4RsokcyvONbqD0kY5yeop009luNRf7B8R@rdKDtmemabReuW695qCCzMVqXJ8kGbSVsd43G8npvEZ4JpshRjSzPiISxf@Tlh80kiXlebGG/V5vgWOtxEs9RuKplUkv5uy9jHpHgJi14z0SRDinGHk9L15PtRkxrevFmCaJiyvGqyxGhCZDTH8miBmiBTQqW7U4i5T@M@QY82UQ71tol2dv/cSNRJIznj8tQkZZxcgp5w3I5LmySXBh0YX8BNnGi4iZBKFM5rb8xHeeXCCZwMI0EAQisOC@k@lOzgpp01wUccHaDjNGEtVIYkoqcN28IhcfqfEIy98uvNHW3x0BwXysfrAuk6gUSrCs41D5K5b06vR81rhjJFChriM0iRtGhKNp3dvVV/ti2UjyBIaU7Wlr4lD41x1UPChv7YSc1r6MBpVbpkZkRlB0KTRQONBVqlnHZDWa5C@4uGwvGwbtDDiBYQ8tnBz0NdAu6810oJtVHkuj1GFleTW0abqwobUiRlKHkH@fVQFFWXF64EIBSMqXy1TBDg1pSxx6EAu96xOS@DqO4jKlgtY1jSR/aKmtp5zkgHUXWGx6tWjtKsHM9sGIWZQEixmJ0nRYR0ltlZUig00c3ExcrxZHZ70hykEBveF4pTV@heydIw6TkhIEf6LrmpRDkqK6@kOZgTH6@6mcSEvzn1WclKLU2mEn0SDI8K5cnUp6VMaqbalZVs0UxJoodr15pJJFK4NsKJVPhz//hqiu3yPLEJtRYZGS1D22cjEjutMmnd5v8aq@d8KdvoGAaefTPcLL@aEmIl45R9vgN2tcxHBvDd/qdbayxTDSY6VgD7pTOXXRxZELLGmsdUj2ZhpWs87SUOCsyatt9R7w93djJuX0/GxtDoPByulkolMPGJ7fze2FZjKynqF7O5i52Lbrc4uPrL8P1JkWV/GHJIgIpZQYfUJTQoYr8/PJXIEMCBsiJ3QV9kxVr/otOxQzDghBKdR90mObU3BMUTUJQYvbw/5A0gBqkn2F/QQLTvF5WMvqtAFE0NxRxDUWmYBF/mzekZkQcfOrDPTk6qGBgEs7FmonnLrW58wQyCyCbcWey@2P2SmifnX4Xdbt9THxABGp4CFr5NFtjZsQuUJAtOGPl270XM/mg9FV5GXeteMbLYvA5wZmIycSaMX3j4xt8PT@vXAyd/9HOephVq8kM08yH8U3sqf5p3tbP4O4AVPiS075T7PBg4LabTZGaa6vUITp8Io0dlb@baJ5PF5T0xTbPbc4Oos9H12VkDNd1lXcD4sufu5ZbckD0hbv7TdbkDGpYEhsYJPlfuVgJXzf55YvFy1OncTSpyGADp2O@SiBIJ5c8JRD4D4BGohx/RE160fyrQsN6ZcCgiCg6CdUzLHRRookAud79V/e3KqdVqamnw8KGq1TbpoVBQtc2a2saHzU21Te@beP@hurK6ui4yd9v9Qh83zcdvapNg8A7nw9bZcJteKa2Ke2Ow1kYXLxWrS976UrP6fGM9Lh7VNnGtn57@89/@63/@@38r1vTL/8DLJr8c/Zxk8n2/uNT6svTDt3W8H20fLy@dHC0NjpdP18Flf2ev4f3GqBCk5qP@8CS3KLOA9ZXtSM06m73P6KLKhA08D4afSbpU1GIrLi7qr7FEjmIZu9gKre8h7lGe0BLeBB2YXMoTEosEdIzteOqdVggDPJpviJKEC@xApbycrZiNe7iDSTIkpyqL2hMP66yXIe60pJ4UcBeXZqxC1IvDHnbAL1nnleblcgH9RqOm5t/iz2/i083@tXrwyVEPSuqBpx7k8/xTXntGX92lYoTbuZKNlgP5vEcp6dECzAxVHLGix@sHjrUzQe5cbolD9gCScVPBmeUWnJes/viyjARci09zC4hqqmSLhA@ZUGTxy1LvG3XLF8rxLZ@5asOKQlOvYrgy60Ql6V@oQEEshgBpzedCkEqfqsRJH99IxlPRfNF9neNoQgwYZN1/ucPjHh9oLlrqaZvnzFoKYY7YfF6@Ym5cl8vQjDZSpP4UAT5QkeVkiW8SLi8u58TK22olN1NuYdvt08wntg7jcGRs06XQ35TFBGLNbRNuqafvtWhDbjleUfkoOV6xqspP2n6rnFXk/KI7igb6ugLXjgH1Jantm4wk9CgDEjjis78yPcJ4o8B4iproFgmWNVbtPpouI6Gnr6ZTB7u@nBxZRCj@7NDY/joxtt0i3xIx7CA8wEglpnydIOrG2uvKkIl9GgxPEB0w6HBAtZGcm/F@HqLTTmDc7yRI@wyZTc7T8UxNWRwMg9PzwFOLu/3DYTBu0LRFms@o5bvUQrhgAhIYfLrqWc0zCEuLdJcwRZKmsOUQghd0xzo8mvRtPrlzgi41Q0G7XcEgyLATUzL8mumrCTqmXP0dnWCjPCW8k9NILWJZ8sLSSEPK29dmeJhNDZ2cqcEeO8nAyecE1WRkGl7QhS4w0Z7zwS9J8i58BOi68/oWoL6KsPYM9WN2Og17QWZyGnRz5qJ/cV3JvIjxzKEoxRopp6E8KacR74AV6ZE/Z71AyNxk3BnlFhxn4VOsw7kt2vMIO/lObPGLgYqSAHQcwIxvhqh3vUiE5cQMlcbA8FWDLf8JQqcbnBJ@46tgDFb8tOj8eK/oHv38qXf8wPnU@/rpd5cx0SLZzLIFtagPs43E0mOFZsail3k1VmmxcTX4qZfN8Kmn5A6LRQJCpOgc/Vw8/lokhD4tuu6D4qdFIUimy4BJcX59RYAvTqG5mMWiuJhbcB@4pvOdH8uuormVf9GH8sGVX8LCLCp5m57WOcMOgeJ7ur9dyJWTuPh0pfR4pfyYVkKn4XVhGF5gvi3EFyfhNakSMZazNPV8@j3DDRlCfLuOg3X6eE3tlLAmcvck1peUtAjVw5zrySVsRWV84QnKT1Rmd6m44uImeQIcPmLB7yliOZOXfUGJ6aDFfQ7mz7h/jnqCGHJt8naIcCSsDMRGhLdQC4Bsgq/cxKGuGS7LfM/JV1vw3cpAqHuLi9Zs0ev3ClpZc/3ldSjRuDXTfVp6Wpoco1NDNDNCl7QytXxPlTd@fPIf/33vt8XR4sZK8cOQfkeLvy2uPV2UR3qgt0fm7XJxY/E5sq19WxwXaQ1Mj0/@439S@Y2/EBykjJ/Tn41VA2ttvLhRqHKRr4sba/RQXlmhev/Xv/4rtWFJVmyIxbrU9BQjtm4oshX0mHcpXTXQSlmWLqdihS9mAYZYGNLanF5gGHW98rTE23SL2qriMtSer4w9ip7i2TBrxKZCspNh7ClIM5ICVVRQEJDGhKKjLNsNY7YB5k3RVL/c99diWgH8os05kioT0437MUyGlmRZRB3oSI20npeHjdKP@cS8o5I3NiXrRoXE0k7L2qeP1okd3vbDUdTKWkmY4XreCq7CEx986IftC1pT9eJu/9dh8ZJY8ry88rTYweZ@ke24iwOGVBiM/d9JEdTBgGhhyEannhpSD/TP4cLL42hBpNDvJGdSJp4kadmDsCV7WNmYxJRF7vh5cjyM5vipKu3wX1LgETlTB4K0YqV96lHJvf2Kyj9MMko@XvO6wOYtG8dqFxgFsYYdsGzyc9wG7A6a9vi14SlfQuJS8LouWfyg3W4GOs3JLeRNqDQvt3AWdgfVfEfcu8N3Kk5MNP1FzbwRSiHCDkKhwIIOsM7DUUBL9Gqev2A9ntYANyn6rDVxFZeStaPz6lV9u8pRV@ZUfSVVX1GPQktI60l4xvLGpuxsIluq2Kochk0cqc2smGqLTdDmoc8/wCCWbml0cC1BN4dvQBLV0uZoqzK72zxeCxOPXIVyZ0@2FiVydW4xvfzomRxygxq6E@r1pTISEPCCW4GFMr0fyA2IqgkzGvVy4s9vItn499BguA17cCVqu60T56MyLfUuEfsmGvFdSkUk0H5lbRvsnMweCejExVYSgjaPjZe8C5bqVHixxRlNd1Q4DLRxCZXPyz7VUUsl4WU7OnqtBIqgD/lSeeXR49W1J0@fIcrZgm7tbDAo5GMVMDgLCAZr1A4tsvG9Ws0v5@UTQlBPVwnos8DiAA5mXVeua9w@X7n3quWSBlbKM6wrDqMhxfV2JYNMIQ5DHzMCrVGcYd5xfqwcoWHHn9ruV/qf@Nv4B2SGM@5oAyG91Q9vU89UuXNxOFBlwcxOcZxH8KDi6hQ7b9jv7MPbRAhbV2F7qug1PECMzob9i9Mzmzt87drqkAYMEZz9UmMF9TIcpQ7GLKygi@oNh4Z1@6Jq4B1NtwBGuZgSoPMJcBpm2m9loC1NMTqWaRKCZ03cWMURomU6arMzc2evr@q725OILdph6Biub1u2knLHnszgQAaxeq3mHhJ1tbcLvkqqZZKX8arMAq6EfGW@Dh/grnQLgagtqhhZzXrDyJlHljLzYuraNC1K/Qi8ZsAsl24npbnXaloBghhBqHeTEiHmJec5NslSnOxOxjgFL@crlo3omyiO2cGcrizvaotSzsRRBRZyNwDEvk0pLw0pVdCj/FjnwMvS2wjmKLeisTWgzZCTlWo4MyeHmWCr21gcYCPquKEF2t/Y3fLUdp3@7HzY9qAob9Z@QruTEM8341vW@JYrqrFjusD2Fss2t7CZ@g1XlIhZStphbIoghG9HoiKGqdeAemNH014G9VFmbB@nXAF2DbQSbnZH9SCBoxfeA1nQi/fEFQdf1@FvFdm8mpY0iUsVPSxki2v@wLZospDWmkASUt4BxMokiMRRS8rtCynDiwU6a96BXrsYxm7szObpDMvKgorU9p0ikT3LszdSZh5brGi2WKmgH@fxBfPtXN44CTt9fRctYY5beOPeH@ONwt2Zo/D/BXPU/znc8Uhzx6MKZI9wR@I2nG90chj2/gyOORnzHNxsR6cR9oc61isaUfIsACzwgCHukFJiuYS23SBOlDM74eHkfAQjoZVVXAz4Q41/rBv/uAKZy4/b4f@rjS/8gxu/qhu/WsFcM6PntWpnuVv/x7Q4VQmd7IeZ3Qt1V7K5f7Sla7qlaxXMpjO6@f96Swv/h1r6RLf0SQUeE@TAQdzXz@dm0URqB1uNRmpu4ee00y4Hcexnc6WLtVe7mqfFQ6d7EZ9Voa2rP4z/U43/U0gjfkIYOpxFJLahyVpelqdyWV40S97lULhkJS2R9hrP6FZ79YSVrkf0BCVCmje2hnqhQgq5J4npaZOf6o@p9E0mn7viLLJdB8vEwbm1gJYVYdlNh7hovjpI5spaMq9ssw9ktXW4//rhfxEynAef9S00Qh5dexV2u2YmsZdgh4nXKd0YqzmAfaDXHBlW0eRkZEf6tnfCLgs3SzV2bDExL85eJMhRG87/aC11Dn3DisqNLSOija/Lm1UVTHPN8kK@UNsl0@wm6xb/IS59prn0WUXt64XBTaQK9Iaf5sV0nbayujpvDpBSPn4wAEse5Z8zqv43)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ytks5)

Running Jo King's interpreter on official ><> interpreter is very slow, I use [fish-jit](https://github.com/primo-ppcg/fish-jit) instead.
To achieve compatibility with official ><> I use `-u` option (parse input as utf-8):
`fish-jit-c -u fish < polyglot`.

Jo King's ><> executes `/8a7*.` on line 614 like official ><> (and fish-jit), but it doesn't treat \r as newline, so it jumps to line 71.

The code is inside Wierd: `7  8 3  n  n  n;`.

Answer (score 1):

## 389. Befunge-98 ([JFunge](https://github.com/FalsePattern/JFunge)), 16436 bytes

Run: `java -jar jfunge-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -f polyglot`.

This answer is the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

## 391. Python 3 ([PyPy](https://www.pypy.org)), 16500 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse       22222222222222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 11 11 372364376371289369389284373370285329368367374377388375   366392393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:x=9;print(-x is-x and+391or f''=='-'and 241or 1 )#\␍exit(0);'''sss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^;s0::PrpullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t."6F ._#^*2*giogrlopstdisp[]!!?48[]?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4otp:sya:nd=/;k:>;'-'3  5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$:     >2y2* 001- #vk!>9*+'P:3+'D'34#v (\$>+1y'+*+01-2/+10k !8*+55*%3*'R+:8g,:1+8g,:2+8g:' -!#@_,@   9s)
endif #               A=AgRA; >82y/;AC;#^_"873",,,@_>2+^     $/       >0   ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7pdlWpWqW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixZ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7P2f3dNPLa1lBwFC77mA6MuyJVxFiTGXM0u3BVB8YrG9aE8NNM88wWMewnDPw1xjbntpTz@jVwZZlzDbO2IHdNXsAgU2cE8M23xou@OUYe2BYF6OLCes6o5Fu9zw2dk17Qr55xp7pYOlPuydM73gTV@9OTMcGrwJjL2xLH3V6OqPgY9fgkYoMQHVPKM6yT4mxJ47rGZCC0zU8z0HHMjjqruk83n360ZXwaoZ9pEOmxpYxu5K8qrJPTcPtXY2hsU@OHz686pplX5Mcmz28niU1x3anE@dgchV@nu0ODFtnmlyWtaueBUDmxLBKmVLmqlcR6tOYmN2ldMDjoelC7ep@LbKubkNtYV1uMWM0nsyZxOtft6ywbj2me2zqTXWLwtnTUcdwg4DeRHcnpj1gZ@ZkyCZD0wvjUWhvrHcNqWdY5sicGD1mmRDJ6ftQALTdYyfG/Mxxocp9mI5tzSGi0TX7JkYJ8gEA8UpMhgaHM9LnUMn2BBoH05kH2bCMAFpSiEH4B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjkrWd6escCoJ056xl9fWpN0qwDfoBkcj8bGrbfmAGcDCCOHZ6r11PKmrFo83qvxzLQjiEfJwYzAWuUrQrLZsGdOS5gDUIFOfKBUbvmZTRmUGdQRX2nwvKZDPjvhy6YW93yHD8zy1lDTxv6KtUZwn3mOgNXHwE2egbh9JODZ8zrOi7Y4MawvD/dBKarT9j2NovvP30QZ/WwWmS3I4RVVGPnUAWxwJOd6tYUWki0JhyoHzeMLWCVxTfiFRYHtGgZlsuxHHTbEtPygCQ1UwYD9H8tq8JdYFqJ5VToQXmW1YrxNKbVd/WBaRkc0gAhFbHxQxANnpkcy6olHnLgWH0erEsJFlm2xApFVsyzIjzLrKxBigg@x9RyHu4C3ACtDNlR4c7mOKBF24e2iu1tj/X1kWnNfegEvsvyKisCRMizCpC1EkCAdzaLdxZuytbyFYU9GQLGh/opgJcs8wQpkhESJaxGBV7K1pZCVBHJLk/eG2LygD5AXL7EipB8ATCRgywAdrUSJJ/P8IJ4Q8Oy/GhDD6NRbosZuCHnRcBDCWogA7jMIDKLcIMdaJ4GxE0DSqYBcdKAoGgamLOYBIQrgF8BqrPg42uoeyeQEE9H6xHygaoDGBWxjYRMRSQBBKgtloU6K7AcNIYsNoZ8lkH@IS/FAgNaVlJZKcdKRQb4LGcY1I0K@cKWogINVSE/KgKD@lehAaiQJxWwrQJQNZtnQgTZahb9IW4W4gJq1BzEyYEZKk4t4A3xoGWokKQKaWpaedEQIW9aHsqbz1IL1QpQu0XwA7xpkFcNmpMGudVK4I9xS4DDEjZgaLYcETriAWoFmzy0Q0BGHvJDcCEsmLViluNPt8ZDvYMUm8fs9DFqAbtCAdEIUTNYPHjnEJuQlQyAwV4A2degBWSpx8A7FyZvqQCkgeCNnklE2jKBfqkhhoppapCv9fFkgTa1QDkazyfD0E3jbg4QTxMIoDHQu/PQE3pfOvRcuBay6KoRvV0AyuTQ1QPq6kw9awEkNOQ0Sso4Na2FW4nceobe65ve8N0irzlKpGPoE9s8WaSSz6cjSNUjHgX0WHIqZqNhJ6YEQ9ZgiKZFWbQihhk7YQUtZVlVKXsdoz@1B4ZULkXyRz6TqTuBwWWRZpk7u@ZgAOPyAo6apmLSYLlwzlMOrWx2IoSOiF1M0zVhCL/LukNgKkLPModfLi9gZDWEMdc7OLJLwInBSFDGsatvzljnbpdGjkUGs4Sn7tAcB4ErawNHKpcSmZUKkbZBmHtbyoSkGa@W/Nox7UScxZPCpQDjDecuo6M1DGqf4kiFYy82XRhbHeIcFuQzYQejYxKQtjzQw8hrARmFSunqOArjmGTQmBrAMScyg0SAFTScU2RdaWBcSsajwbPjIqcKnE7PcF2GYYG99dI0zHrTjme8mSIvtchXH8ZtA4b3vm5aYQZoHNEnxATAO@5BevPlbPddZ0SDzQiHUctxxmtYFhi0zxDQI@fMWGR9Mabr47EFnBO4G5xxg8yc6cRzE4MeTZVnCCJhPKhwAEhJAcdhukaXcO8XHWJngTdZzmKFafW7WYRyP8JSZaGzALvhYRx7alkV4HWMLsvWlZ5xqqALZ7uW2S3MQ8CIATvlg@jowC9jzikXIaS7mkws3nFQs54zWi4aH18PwqIPTWSOrDN9DrXXh6HVmOkj4OoZss7Qc9kIWgyvQawJkFuwWAes59jxSQjlzAVGFgodloSYZcTJxBwZIAE5EAVrPEeZxtGdctaZQ1MmbOVkEnl4Tq4gShauIoo75CIOvLMAy9ebdhFrmLZpUwsCNslDPt8FUsndhInLmk0dbhd4urEv5clowIDPMWsRIcHjvd3nvrsEEflUw/ZAtPBkZqIMBi1/4PShsZ2ZUHYgWBB1AbtLSEAUhE4zuSsLhHJsQKMTi5msOx4zcIdBCZrnw0wJ2FDntcnegqc1BDGiO3XdOZuNoSbMEYSadJ1@H1rvW2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1Qyth6h5xCB6Y6Xi7mwbRoQxkbBZO/ZL7KBAWgHprWPEio2@UUBxmMqAqFCtzlDa@uAKSxCdzwntAixRYy@48jo3nMMjxqL456EXR8T84wBdQ3oZ/0FMRohgw6t1CbBogeUx@9eCB8TFFYWBpPyW8FHhg1dpwutEjo9VB/W6S7rg6AdYWFR1tC7XWM88duJQ@TMtCM8/@FD5PnJVfKByd5Q2LzHtq@0GggatpwIL4syEGZ97IsiOtJaX5qXiPEIxU5OWaz5teQhxOmV1MVXGGYpB6/ENXkYU5dAAYiIxHSCpASpo9kdIi2cILUhfht6mzu9XnxwiybvjpjUD9PG3KhAdgRZCZ0wH@thSHBb1wHJYwth1ZccMOiSwy2gdW@0ArITZtLqRV1lRZeBKN4GdOTYzgqogMwQLgZZ9qG6oMb4HKmGboWNkbqLt1RHSLAXE0w4kMEYOh47LvQMTnTmNJtAVRZpXb4QngjHiqTM7i8PrTBkxHHAn@AoCBHGlg5tAbsY9lSQrHSgFEDEuJAMNM/hKUYyTL2eYPn5OyPSzxsTjKW2baBwprtzDgSKB8MzJDRnpusCGTzFQYKPQcFgIlM7hTFB7/WQsiI6qN9fTVzGFr037Zizq5J4Fx3l155wqrusj0K4C0wHdKJEvO/Fk1Vyp5gRL1FxxhOFovKnCAEpkAxVnuiDXA@DxEMgNM/ndjchLnUxMc3E6aRfEpNgwIicR2Mfg6hwNXcoPmCjGZ1AvyZblQ1g@JYkeEroRjlBD0VGD90FPgM6IUiZ5XKvo7MLoB4uk2Z7XBQJRBJVzoVpGXYvTMtHBOYlWl6ZJ@G5XTJIkVENS4DBqeQ0SCwh8AMxQRFFcFAUf2xFB@L2uB/xNdxxatNcHEtwViTJzkPmFwaABGXGBObD7JqTts@u3L0bMC4btRo0NuCmgGz2klGJNpi0lIFSQ2CZuBE/EXniPJ9g30gkobwY@JLnBtgmaKm1OjufDF3ocWS/FCAQoFWwsSUHiPXr@al5Mu1drWgbHTGQiL0OmCazOxGrAgz@vDfUbsJqfAmrIPXGEavYeDE@gb7WeMkVK1T0g7mGh@xvzc9KpIYTmAO/ra5EEY/quy0a9N68a/ksATdBZ@fUqAPZP/Ens0JClPZ5gqDTXuupHAh2Bw6HPds9flTz@yL3VDqmXVlysJyubpHzJgYXg7iPD@4f7R79YnsFDMvsVK46KGauVMChdjqTBvZUyclaZTMKYwH4Qftm2BhxOYwo@N5McmYRVmnehcFlFqDz8OhrV1ECnBCig1IAM95XWBoeBpguoaN7wyuDMBukUpBkGCUIy6QDFsAMDZh19NeD/Dybvn2LlXc1U2PfHXNmTXUOIHBUDuwgnoyeVxiwwKvT5yMixQUu1LRxsWFhioYM8vMRcs1XM0OsdKTJfHT4cP@oRmD9eTWJgijeBHgp3e3J0OatKYjgq8IA@QNTl6XkRcaRn6a8rkRwt7uE4EXdsjXwAQDKOrLDJGsUFM0bQt73rpaNXKVu2ALIThCu8pVRfqj7ZTMayQcOcV0UeVeNouSxGKxCp5UjVui7PGx183mjmCtHh63uIs1eFCgtDMA4EPCNLnideBK6yAsu0mer/ew/f3wt4x4xkSAKSEHOPIvJlJZnCSi9SCaLe8oeSGiOZcifEsUTmZhUlHiwNiB3PRI@I@H3Z@YkkUnyt5qEsJD67u6B9iAI7E9Z00wGCQ0oi@PI5PZxja/rQRuxHcsZOGwL4nDuMEgQ2Ka1xdwdOPa1GtLREYsaw2VCoL84caOPYawx35LgSLGi4ipfcNRt7wyotFrIIpIIQwRKofDya/1UB3Qtyv384PN9GETUfCYTmjN0AQoicQhdaOpGXMmBSZCQ7OdnZQHDJcNrvT3wkCJrdlhon9CFEXcX3isdiWLKysrwK7P0sXMN46@d@ZWmBS68aYEhgrKDp88eHzzdf7L7WXOi5fNL9lymXADEQXod4IXkIccb9tYt3jWxWAguBn3Dxe4FVGAKAkqwYjT1XCDcMgaReQbWtBq@2Jr42BnacS95tTBn6Cu9tru8CT3BzseD@hFB0O5ZKIy4fMUax3NsP8PJZOxVFAV6@XDakUFoVV53HUsfKBQPBgbLUlQUXQ4OcV7DWxUDMuPNDR6DT24B6zCnGUTdGjkgvNC6N5IGluDgadbKMgdDkIVxcdxwk3LYgqk0Sg8kBJCVlbBsRIDJBrj130E9ibxpf1XVSrxdqxktp4hBsKXuD2E3@gaITgkYrQAVyStW1rzbvMvmQKUR0lUgMSZv0SSHx3AssBgwkjRrinJ@gByiFjhfirSCcPRmirO5QKWUfCZXVAt5BcQyENOAZ5Vwzk0a6ZPuUJo4EsCTnD7NG0RaYd/r6nZf3vINQWaB77sDRc02XjabdgsY9OZdyhuuPTfmrYbaSlbZ9ShbfvhkFVrvUvGw7QYO0HbJCE2T3mwNPevp18lZT6fe1WPKZDT2xxxpzJ7sAiP11gF63TOifQ8jKFFPZWsprIKB3ykrJoQsjCrgAzGlQIeCkRaanoL5koDpRfYQWg7QrUgEtpjN4OXgezwidASFbmz3phP3aI0E@RqcLfXGgESabO4ilfZwfnACo2PY8pFKQ@UikWZnRhzn0XWPz1ZCJH@dP4gPsloIgWblwxlpO9zZAI2AYpF4DpQD2hVOmw4Xs4wo9ENLgwQpTzj5AByETasHA6AzEJkXZJcXhKdELstFOrGdMxuhdQxWkjrmhE/2O1MX17vNXrRsEDyr8TAAjQoXoeu0MN4xunyWlUemUoAQqLORMXJwKgG4KyIFBhVB54vqKAt6OGMN3Soj4YohwJfYvT2gYl2DzxdJIxSioEnts/jEVXalzxVdegut@QbeCgsfqWK/0o8DBCxvcaBZEn8GlLgTZ0SBPqX5FvS8H7C7Aq4YQomhhYl6zRkb9lWZj0uEiWSVtiLE43wR6Dy@sbERr8Tr8TSYdsC0jaYdNKXAtEMmiUwYTkYTxUiTCX0bFAPdWvHLRgB5lmxhG5gh5/DWHCf0RqWSbaX1huq/NXwnoSoA8xBawhfAiSdrNTQmk2L9DNdsgH@PlH0P287zrmuOfRR8DAwBt/s4yBISQLxHbt41qiib3oyRUc0FodFAFjPhxpuNTLPVPG/2Us3LeBpjJ6t6DeRDIF6TxEgeuM50DIxbI1eRgLYlG9lKq9qpxTPxrUSiJFmQkJ5M3iklUzrHdSJuQJtKNJtxQKmPnUZ36BK8WVpLJkNEQT76JkgZlpWIy@clSL@TbCVTcYibjKeBLNficcALLTh6VGicEeCN6KE5A1RCx4QhLrqmQASSFqewu35ujIdzNxognHUDLhtn0Bf7VXBbD1LxKJV8y@NHGbolST/ge3k4YG5x8g75pfGcU3eB57SpLO2OCsbdU6k/cia68okMQpMcGS7jG3FFkmAkJB8OiYr9xPSwC@u24Uy96EzjyglQTB1cj4dTIJbBFrU0tCpzLBjdocPim/cAOgvXe3AowaUriS@ABQB6XRluJKLIleBiCXAXtKnIBLpI27FoVkalTHDSE8zN5wvjN3KYWpXisAwmZA5sxzUkQAnEEGgHFe3LE@rBuvQBzXxdW5fwfWlIQ8HbNIAiPrQcnXDLyXVkPWg8isQH@RyiHBk9wQL60QfyKPO6cI2esiXQKq3jDmGEgNIgJdbC2hr5HorjjXvyZAZRhQQOuFFPLt0B03nGepqmFbr5fiXww1YByB5CJaFUaoOIG3hJKngm/Ure59NCgYz@9PDBPp87ocEWh1ecR2uPnN4U@Epfbjoy7EGa7UN7Mm1nZAIagvhvT6wjx5lwKR8s62ZmuNBsjqaWTnM@V6dlbozXdTqORVNBN0VdhJ@6nm7pfBIq8N395Anw@i@On9fkSiSQop@Obkwb5yFXJ8vxeRBdc6T11mB5yOMNU9zMizhuBTs/kcz4HgX0mPr7PqGOAvciugddCtdQfPcSuo9wzyfwyv4sAllDRz9gmQLiPlDc9OY7nquZS3RfK4OF4VQKxxnHRW7PVY3cTyf9/pJzlpxPJCRN1sI5R858P@iSjBjNUp4Hws2hS2GigAoUJtwjujZckcLx3S1yuLL4JNyEMDSsYGnxCDgWXD6DQd9CvgqEFmTR@T5OAzjsMa6SEOnGtTfWBSbUuzafAZ1tLPHQQmyDOhAMbgqyNMKmwvy57yp1Idvx1yw9TlYdkPlpWmW7zle5UaZyuTin8Fn5zTaA2K5Xgw1364JhSvF4GIygUt4gBhWTFvavFTXcpuHRZLtAUaqCp4A4MdMyUnNW3G9dxBWP0NBnYrM5u5PRPgO5BHdMbt5VBkaV9jitwVc18In7PGxnziTg@DAUn7juDoHOsNRsGZVQP1O771g9ia@SQYNhXL7CCvI3KYQ7Of0Nu4bpBps4aRctj4r0NbL/8xrcK1Vavx4gsmM0BATd55xdnKRPL1gDhrxT2Rtb5qTFLuWJ0x76O6Xsq3tLOQ/quvrcE/w9LjW2e/TRJ41Mi0MQRjqufJV4Lc6CLcrAOAOjhHvJwYQ7dSbmhDgB2olgYnlVGTI1o0USyD7A4AlUWZiQXyLM@oVxsShL3wBJNWFgzr35KM2M5KXct/TJxLB5m@PLj@vRzdeJ/GRqlPyOv@hQYRlamQHO1EQ/yGKVPT9@sH90JEPL9RLxfVzBqUB31LtDYFDWFTrAZLTwFXanF2d3ME4SxXYBuhpIH20/PjTqKjR6kD8gdaQdA8NNgGMSF1@64EzrXRSRc2g@gnC/VXdCOAqBJYwklImAVVbm/4XNRS0/nxVo8SnCJKA7cbcCuDWT8tQ238geDDTEt0KQOBdWYbyobSaIim2qSX9D3QiXjkHCIqYRStBoMOktUDkILLJWq8r3AEBYFMDcAWJXFKkqaCd7TQ2qvgbOwNIQBD967R172chI5VZqcxUo2lzmb0Ln5Y/ARQjLoD1jZbKbCerv1zoyzwNfC@SU@wWJ01dOYFTYJjeIfM6Zggcbpojo0P6q5X1Sy7uwoJMhKaGpGCxIQBJi/hEBv82SP1F@kHkwGjkkkuw8RLqGKGcXF4RDtqkxwiGYVMYr4zKQPoEwPXagNI/94wFR7oB6q7@RBPtsUxADMWt5pRZ9OAuvnF7hTqVTMRqPc4emfeLQek9oamdkNY8cYRh7dGJdj4mbUOmxFDTMAw@rrcudN@r06bEiAC17@Avq5EAT6j4vDEykrhzRi@bWV6S8vIlkKVl/eyqNtGBm0ptbQkrlEgXudzrmuqCABNwXFrxXBAMihe1Zk3OyGpw3wKkYGI@AcHHpZVH0q/uP2BLe/X20/vs/f6MH@L9eO0MYKHDmMTS0YejGmpL6ayvLj4oWeqyuWD5BPrVMnRBDpttAdnUXiqRboWE1aFqElyQY/ke4pODXOLRNfADXeEMz4znnK4LBe3UiqxbVbCCZ3XVhr@zH4knR8g8Idj1CAmeCTIMiEenilWDM@BJMRMRGMnZ7poJNU4waM6/34XQy5U9gXG@tRHOM90190w@Zyesd1VD4zvUbqtzVT6Y9RxqfDEI@tbAi7KL0tAYsATvgLwe30bi6@LyAfCd48F4XbDG0KWf0uq1VePbUG0sdksJ73EYdYXRDCq7Fn@uCmP4BvtCwHmumRY8PbIk@dGgo/m4IBfeaShGkmVfQbOmdOfIgwy/fysKdBUBxat1UKpNds7Q8Hq@Pj5IkxS@XV8eeyV2Oj1VzBArfzyrxWTQqsL/D9ZZaheHKHOmWpPUixrXEfNXGhGtBwzVNioOHL@gExo2NHAek7tTS3YXphia@yEewjLBuRtofNp6ZXQfYgTFTi7KqBUNHZMAgkhlsjVskhNuJ6RHZ/mCuQmNwnEQKTatJgNOd4JbRNW3qAwga36qJG2IjjUR21mGq65zhvZZ9GIJoyp@rR7S3K3P1AcRJsrqWDuP42uFgaXIQJx9vaahnpmfQYzViT1ZmdNK1Vrovd4Fg2i86jXdbs/ZMy/HYc3rehKCBC1jgz9UNOopLU7clmgyPmm@gQcEeh0WF6tbAsQqlgaLDY22tT90@0n3//aEULqRQqnoLhQrYH8dW/fdaun6iuCe3VRAdWHRxf2vEeMMQu4pM@Wsv60sHggEu3K0u2cNMiWLKCp/qW5MwLrmc6fPg/XMMHetQGwwd4zmx08DdYYRyCQwTl7PYP09quZtT630YUboGtnhbISKVe2IZMFjR81qVMi2jfskYaibz4SSqb02NqbFS0DjsvDbwaP0NQsaHZyrjF2PTn6nHxQE8mhKGeutLhh@Uaxyn0XYjMdEts2vczsosE7UxcN9jFJ2fgeEZGq7HGNjT8VKtLkln9tHNKBuOgy7t9JZyhz5flg6VbuGUlvhzz6D7RomJS3i4QayWz2QyPgMTWXFZstwkSWXDuK9N/lxKmFwWKS/C4iqbGzGuToPQEt2CuJYEaesEewpcLiu2aRuTOT4/kJp2HMf6MjUFRBUPDDsgrUq01famGrvG7viHSNhi6sLDCY9Of92kBR9tfNkS8INC802VHl0S@qDalHDRc4QLUsvWm6dvIgtMt6WCh1txTohvvrXW85L@bIgql@Tijb2Oc6hOx7B0/poVcjfBK8vZG@EtEw1/sRYXd/mS7mIpPnaFKI3ngCyzB1LK0BgZZL2By9d7qCbDf60NNHPwXuc9M4yuMts3uusCjE2gCzY@l9aQI8zSxLFBvprgPj@UUyzcSeq7rqPAwarfSiQfjPSBwfW23EQpFxMWuJuGi3UL4@qpiwrfQdOFaAuFHOubBHSqE2PuBe@VAJ/Mu1Cv09Ht021XOn8X50A/oLev28J6fYi1h87QHhpDvm88tK3rHNAeJ1zPzk1Zh1wPhriVbTxe2uIexaflWNaH4BNJIyeUjtNfmad9PPyKJ7e@FFx@0t5/3Tp5p0847UDD2l4zNKYwLnnOxBkbEtnWBbVwooc/19HQYJH6551BulHOB4wE758X/q2y5UB3JuMxvdpja@rRg6JKdGb5Nr6pz7em0KZIxx3Ib51RR/YdZX/fCi2BryYxHXPSHeKhcd6yjYHT6Q7N2zLtK6pQgikfbv0g2RUxYzLpATrLlgnodecytpda1P85vg7WVbo/e8SHtdBwA7@yaoaOjmVLY/2k6/HZUDSxCk4IR3ojP7xdoePvlTdTc7IAGtnLFE7v8mUJNKzLu797Yi1nRWckFmTY31WxtpUSk44MuWRkgOFR1yW7vM8t0sWyWf5Yl6FoKSlHkX0pXwbd/t4fmh00I/O24L7UvpY2La0c5OzhdOBdJ5h8ur4HLBo@1k9b0F7myJQ1jFm67b/WoVmzFDzkCO828FxT48Y1lfyNiyoUTrUk3THh1YYXVN107RyaZY49/mRSf@1SnL@XCWTxq@uFHDfz1cK0XzE9o8@XQNB0G4s4clzciQw8iNTFlXScQUdizhkvTrhsZwBEXbLYInAQdh3bsnKb0OrqD8dM6bOnxkDHvdaPzQlu1lzRKqjJrtpedCvsr091z/z6FEq2rrGhxga@DOlGj/ajbQW8J/rA7D5aqogwkz6C/Z2e/LXU/NHpel2cDU0PdzSFhhsmprDJ8UaMra4NcsOKkFfn7UNlFYsOxI9Brgy9am7dGc/xtNicTDdNq5sTmmX13@tEx3WbwG7MxNl0NJ56/mt1HmjPVHQWenRC7t6ZCcClN0Ba2VC3JqtnqiNTrsCF@YPiwriOG//ctJwB@7yUYcC0AROGzPmKhnMfhudnuCHHtVe0REr7A5c9caJDcnnB3kDdGlkmmbY5uXk2ZzLBzTnBGwvDRw48oaA8xqd878tCkI5XY@Tx7bz@4mjyLeM7tLznztTtGmgM9Y1ExQI/VWMv2H2MJzoc1JdyFpXSuo4F3QsM1sou03Xs6URyp/aNo0LhxlGhgtqmIs2AJb6@/@RFMtoaaLf2bVxooI9sYVq7YeBKIzNtYMTW09Hl0IEs8YDrSTqircK3xNlFZU5dItcPnFXyzrM5DCAfLDAB8Z@OHhhdXDa8Ne2nzhPHdmA0GgOhHB0Z/Mz/0kaP1REx2mM81Q746d2azHMCu2YQ4tyGPjY6UL/WwvQhYxEH/ECf6GuGIpobJPkvNN3aVkyrY7ivadIvYl4n0i5n6JExI9lifYPhfVCadLucJcb5uKU@srRi440dx@ZPorYZeKlPbqYqMBTQ48MXymXciL80L7BSPlsu6uEp3yVi9LhSinVldY2OY/HnDXuSbJPvCdBd0/CUx6jjgNwKOSYB9@XdSEOKN9KQhWgEnOyp7tEi/WpRYwFSnX2JLUBD3e06uBLmG27YnRNRTHALmQ739vONAx1A/Awolt6d@spCb8uWNeqM6LFWYIjU5pHRwVNBHdLmMdFn1yuTzwz5qgwiO7pCBQABucJOXWCJZyCNJG8ftpbkqGWsmmN6EKVeu1xOm3Uk2zS6b3WcNXMIX4u56SV/KLPylIxr5qoj3YhmkRWdTrqv7EnLW9eAobEMaTJ0QeZXJjdNbwdqVlash0xHBi4yL6/CrGVdHW9IhXVWr6eHxNU1JF/XH9CSUO8f5w@l3bWcJ4KH/@H9jxUYhNuFXKB6BEjX7Sv4kPmpa/uvD2mBzxxv0jdnh5BvPAWwjpxgsfIQBV68Z6Bpa10hoPbsqcVnHwaRfVejHoljEmliliSLyPXEkAz7VCJFcLPrJXL4oS9lF7X3Toye5OtBwJUG6XFw/isM5r9XLKBGaSNu9lQVjthZIedv/1yF3LOAMgC/5UyksUdvZew9O3h8eCyPPXXl@LQ7xNMR1/i4JcUKWikTmZJ6rbuR9U6@Ha1nehPl/nNV2nt8IGOANfjmKxoSvHBlbum1dt4z0OKq6GulIPQ1JqsZxEfHTx6nFkc0WWJv6DojIxn13nv@PI0nTT5@vtI7Gvsh9I6@M1sb/WBfVZMrmu8Lm1YH11HPFSmtg3RsgDQKjfER18tyK3PVdcZG73g@Nj6BwRMpuPeByRfWFvKpfmoOsBey8lpEUUdlZbmQS0Z2ZoOwbbjhe119nphjpJZdein8tXY7CnIOWcXNruYeblrxv8rFsIy/E@HLRVIz11trVI@wont/34ypqroOz8/1PtQry6@trOUAq9aHLef0A5aSDV94kUInaQKtSjJv3UdelEZAuhV84PS87wjGztptMDcBCJ0LKzv8mWHPdVuitayb2IsKxMZNbTcG@dz4gAWpcIfPKSorX7nGF26pZ4kuGZO3JHzsRqLs7d0/uC3CkY/Lm0N99PQFe6Z7qITk5oDRHBsfkOMFZ/Rawnkr1IC3djm15wIo7UZ4g/Hq/lxhz3W359jz2e2LcHQGFYd2Ui4cwkIbBTIsc2auGqu6fF7r2eptRrelzQ9xOPMlPjiqnMYH9P7b/0xVMxlSPYRvNcOtt9RM0MFZAk36HPXZRb2OD0LS0EW@RQaH5Epp9LExw@0ofDZ4lVC/cnwr3DD2FZPrh5Ob/Eo3@OVuSO@aHzqyrJxRbwCYv8GP5eXQ@7FjnQ0deU93DW/F/uOVGbqpIOUbClKOUGdfWzotLPrm9Sw@Hl3wXytb67ExcXPjodMxcyvLsNtHJZPsCSpLv@7vb6fQXdreMnD8Ix/cvjq9s6mxMqEn@tvVHkRpTlZ6ARE0hlM6EnHde3mBtAM8r2EPTK5fkd13Jvtku0EwC088r96LYI4fTMfrcwy0ET9JcZWcLwX8FGRm58xj9/Fo3IJNXyH74/641e7reFoWTgyimtFHx7tB6zp8rmiRFBe5@OzZkjMeHp0cPo@4ucZstk7olWbrZMiVPotUnx7nlpLdrr88XYGs9eeNgN0Aehy@1/JBnNh9/Pw6SUDxbTgZWYHPx7q9mDFdqrCeM6GThis9n81ntI1yZU0P@S62VX5ud4XzkmAPA7JpQtqe0m6jZv12e12rPDY@o7UHYIPYhLMlHKiveMmY5YZBDinK2o7qnCyYn6XsPh8PTXu20mu0Lg7tIk289lZ3g1323HLO2ONQq9A68qCtBq6fGvY64rTqsKJUzt7MhWWvsFTr6oV/vcR/rauS@@sYtSs0AzdE3ERNMP5RV3kYWD7RkreG//h5EPz2sHuWg/P3PXM6uj0wgU2lbg/o3kD@rgI0bw@GH/s4GTqufXvQoDlVKveND8zExgeHHM27zgfkodPv3x5o33NuD/Rkak1MlFlWB33qTC3UILDKb98drHSvb9ebTbkir/NEbere0E2u98d9kc7UAxnIDIlnGFF6bU6WHIM2E3VD5e6GLdtO8grcjx32NVTjvgIVbz@wjj5@uC7c8oLNFJf46UTwwrhuU@94voJ08EPqQOOiHzjw0r6KKq7UgR@l9@TgKxSJhA2oSC5/8iuqFwDVgCc2UQ3uJukAgLAXF2zDP3cPHmJwkt/XNIDaMk17aqCqAP4hoEltE5Kp1dR8me3gN7YqTM1QmvjpwDJXShgk1mCb5/4p@kpFvWQbNSZWRObrMQh1jHM92QAYNfxCoZh0orLNCfhsBmfwGX3yhV0wmjqUuqhIFWyyEtVGUvW1FECeNs@fHTzbf368e/zieSPTuvS1GASlsG1ILdCVcifbE6HwPt5AJOFa80l7hgXJ0edocMrRC8rF8BNXy0WrLRVtUShxB@Nsntu2opAiB0W6hPxJIk@NfHFgBScOOygxVZCvw6PCdSqQagioIw5apDSh0iossyrhsQ7s9abt@1/9Ihz54lcDK/jdQEzYV3QOLXvgOD0/Rc9gt19Big93Dx6/ONpnQQYXrebM7E2GtXKe68HnymWgnvom7WytsbgfJQ51VavFH8YBMXE5ziqkeoN00ENDh2ABdlBphx97iyU2CT5gMB5WivKfv6FcxmU8pJGEsPEgU3FIFto8NZSNjQ12DI2EPTg6@GT/iGH@9x@QM6IIQbBjPPf/Zz/u8a@4BHq5gi8muiPihUmvkRDV/REoxFjo7ECcU98dr/9uIn01hTRjhJ9rCb83JQj0NR9ot2ekUvOKusUkaUDj33n0tWEGCVETCr78gOuBqNnS9dip6ZmolwPz0EdFk8uNHbcQknJVme3iRyHx05M6fVIIsj61J1yZm6/SKQYtTQ5pTpptUmb5B4jESMD49gY09o4BYhLzbBMI9aTCXkNLxDW3CtfbIkn1@LUoAegKmSRkrSMBr2mm9JSmq7z/tX@iDKoMzBMwf8c3zzL3wfYrvq0P5l/l5pcKNrTrmiwXeYlmCLXP@iXgGQnxj7iPfAvT5rpyFohDhZsBYWXmCKrplLCOwXkK/CkBPV7ASTQ@gUqD5gY15uvI4ekZbiuB6m8rioJNCkV3mcYbY8a3C19Rg1vIF3KqApmUTgOA9N2KAepB4ACTyQp0E@HUHNdegTi4vb3NRJy/M2qFKq9ZZdN@mRVfhRndhLDC2RAz12AQB6IsYoBf3Y8Go09KTWJUpF5xNY6Eq@fAsET@OHyh3fYRIbIEIIvjyMAPIczws6kT4Gp9dc4d/NBo5JtGmz4gSYUxiUxJUfC1yzx1JtB8oJMuvlrGtcvgdnk@BKKeVI9/TJi0KGN7lK/3rIVShODjSX5fk5EGcFDZzNXRNFq34qcI4jmCqIirmm/jJWtOmnZL4W2TQTP94YrGbIP5l5XBmjbLy717XYdu4qoGXEQWu/fcdnCi8iEUhiU0RcsqaiG5KFIut7JIfon8ZKA4qKjrApIDMgUko2uYr52xt7u3f/Dx4bPn1/TEUsj41WBA9@vbqaYkpxut0BCPFmu5Su4/VJ4/uf8wqIhFpgsRagyE3y@JelNJFusPCHJxnu1q0Vbl8Grp1uf4U67x4mp@s9pNWaNI1/KhZr5EunSmRHpIJ0OvJq6VVmErn78pSwt4SgT0Hj/Wfy2rieT5ZaMFUoIdi19vCSs6wsuYvIWdAExNb2tTwcZ@vXBYsPAz38f48UQv2hezq/uiuJlFNYSoVWTinCwUNfoOEY9IeYNkgEQKshIEXdv7DjmTvlAnqvHPkHP9hVHtbJEMFzI3YTwC6jj4ojlSkYUyZF8P8FD3hpbZEQKteFwfcKC2NFQFzDXaJZKC/0kdnnDC/8b5rDKTaQNpIonUjmCl2U2qhQN4SQE6NHJ3z6bekD1zxvwTC7RR6IERmI4cIL8Ppnxi0WAfT0cQrk@vI4MWbYFySxAZMBkPs8p5KaASvmbhWQp1N0N6DdQv7BdcHvXyiVlSHhqznjkA2p5IpoGi3VHVFgu1D2OhSduwHRepzha1cGNX/AiVNUTR/qVUUM8WGdAbumzaPWOWiJ/Fk5UWpI/u8bNPT@NJcVVbIlXYvm7o3lWd2GH2i@rNlESf@L0zUDi9ilqUy9epBLhdBcx1MwbfdyuX5aEn0Pc6a8i5P5@4j8EIbESiP9LHLDG1uV5LmZE10UzYaVL4J9W5zlybpVIkUMGLPGRGMftk4uN3QrfnLKHU8JOu4OrZPXy9NcesocpyC8yUSJJt4ncX94DjQk2vSQGEYIhSIbA1bEIgZkCOeCeReQOHOOgPYeFF2kFXeNNn6Ghty0GcUKlZ/S6LfEdzmXMUy@WKX6HLVLHMoPVdJ4eyAmCv0bmArwfs@iqvAGcg/spCbEHIr1O8GKUb4xl55OvKguzEInquAxVaDGAttFB3hy7eiX0b@grwB5XKi@OH7VJSEVmoc2vgmj1ce@WfaghFPP/jWtBNlaWg8SqX6D7CaKjdtM2VeqGSzYfUYcQrJDUWRYOvIToQlr1F21TVG1u9H9GvBQiZwwHAP5vcDsChRtpgUnaF32pi/7OfxZDZSGyq6knbPU3F85kqPNRqnuXZnc2mJG02MrV7mzpIUZM3sybI5MpW7sGpMez3DgZKUxRZluUUZev8/Dz@cOuZ@TLPClLP1ApvZvPLbCH7ZnaZVUtvTsZqoSG/mbXEUi190mLPnn32rv0uKc5O52/EZkKL7R1eiGoORf5YpczOdwrZ2EkZxE9Il7ET9haukz7DP5nf9iJmHc2dPoiwcZHFmk3AuCoWRUVpxFvwJ3H/FVxc8G/U5bq803r3LtnQ9clszkzTHHu9HtzOEDhILfmcgbx8Fyg9j6CwJr1JgsJrNOtfn0/IMzbbNQaD6b5e1/DYunyvXZ2b04eTJ59/Glwv8Hp7FIn21v/QcyqVkKTGinmKSlvPx/CT0X/2k43L9Pmz9vaffXOkGBv4OsTXdy6foPm5mr@zsXHn/v1cLq1pGjc/@/zZL@7u7uYepPPPGvmdnJTZ2P7TP9nY0LRtTdloeZ7aijdOTj4TtUxOlP/sR/H2s2df97x69v/8xru6io8iPE5ZEegEXFmmghGfJbhV5LE@9Iq9jUErV2Nz@rVjgfv5BlPrO8X/8r3DN7FJrK4pn7rwnsTexAqlGDeCAWzZwHYaq8e2MVjhMjZXarUaGIv/5d9C/PrHAAd95tvwqOcDWIV5rC7VKMpFrF4Ag6ppkO7//Y1vRHLIyUSN2LjguscacIm5oibutODaomtbQF2mUkZRgnD2ZDgxHKaW7qp30WKCBV62gR@FMCbNmFrKMXZ4j7GjRiqVasltCS75JU0SKaqqNVX1LpAD6c5WrSZtMa6tNZvN30WN80ma0ho4MGIadz/9h7hiqxyrPze4IyFW2Lj36kG9DmXK1rNb9RRdfkeiPlUsiY5zT2Rp9ioOIkij9eox4yqm62KmpInpdPpem@wzxJU0C1sSXvwZi4Uu2GXZVbelKBDEd419@XCxfbz@/H/78@//@ffo9326/wMqe7V7Zl/ZgkCn0CXqcN2rVLr1ulh3xfMm2uvQjjKVUqWktC@biS2gQK0jpmY@uojns/HnYerNJMWGi5Kt@8mjvR5bONe5Sz3q5nvwwOTA/FKQYQlrZA6xdi0cDK3@tnipcVpvScgQ1aSGWsi3JB6rHlxl1rgH1SRqxbLYqmt57ZDda8/4xYabHnNiIBkWAjz6@a0vylYPfRa2etQpVg@i1Rdhvmy4ML9CrNFQWgYNCIEbu7dR2ShVChVNadfXX9A0o1YKahjGMy92GgsvjtnYAqGxsGledQuqIrSwoAWzLxMOKiuc7NbWXoxqKVtQxapv0tpMrEIj0bKSNmiLGVUMexvO78O1AT/6wxVa8blBLr4zBbl@bbCKuqVllfydwr6G4@stV3SgEGCcYN1Op/O22wGuQ9c7eldXJ/pUn@lzfdKZdmadSXfaBabp6ox@1sk7JWfGZvSXpVg2r27G7tIqj4r/bFHLFnLZYiFbVLVSOVsoZ0tlrQQu2Wwxo5XyWQ0cS9lCMVsEx2K2VMoWcYzLFgrZspYtZ4XYu8YGO@LkrMVSwdVM3Xq9kOW2bySDg7ckObOYEPsHuOqqprItGOgy8ADujowgfONPVQUWA47tvPVuq/FuC3p6PbVNVLZVl/xcwktu32ulpMvLBpirVf@/XQ@NVbq4CQrXukyltl/WgY15WW@kAORLH6QsMQIqt@utbfIJE/NT8723W8AISantxnbN2aNbpp4mxXNOvODcawHg7aXM3ruXksF0DwDUN6FjJ1OpTUnawEG24Q86ELhVTwWlwjwkgO04P/85b5AYgRxcbl/WLxvbl5fb2/Dfpuel/wbXy@1rf3otrjVhFv4tpFHNhlJvKk2f6rTALit1dJGVJhjq8IZwjaxWajXQAJfc@m/zL6cXz9AFs9ySIddCbIttxVCHaTa2JcRevf/if8G7@f6L30fGk8HPqAixc6QPyhaKrWUuvcKD2U9s9oRfNpjxDqzogg5P6uho84eNK1uK8kpmFb54kFBLhaSMI3nb6bdRLYrMXkHQJfKCpJOJWqkgtlPqXGOxbbFQJLr5C9eueDz@j15p5WKcz/igXo9Xnuc9ieRykU8IXNUyqqRe1PmnK/hXhn5h1fWPfmHdJcQuysyoAH4SjCNGiEE7iimKJMHIV98e4cEPXHORULw9rX0mvdiVcD5Gn9CKWpfPNdQO9mvlcp0vF20@o16z9WALnir89zegGKzZh7DNfq07Ak662c/mtSZ@5yAmdd7g7/Fb/LHjLv6O3uCPHb/F39EEf@xJB3/Hb/C328Hf8Qh/99/g78lb/L0Y4K/5lWxWrYqb54SZlFpWLzdnImGoGtupN78ycecVy7AbZq/lf8IrmyuzZKz5FWPWNcaTyqxW9j0k3KsFDxCIU9my6risH//pd7/5zXitFpfi9LmkHLqqfnT65msVageKHK/ei3@lQdJ/vtxqoGcLfIRYjW2qm2rGynQzakftgMFkGZdlhpmh2lNJSsoYLDPPzFlm5Kg9MBnwy4DJzPRZZsAydsaGYOALpkk7M0FTH14D@PUBkAs/E7c@d9RMl0FCFkpS9BlWtY0xMxftptBgcSa@MkDMlVU5IxfMFn68qiG@etVUtlpaucRkbIZyu/GqGW@JTRE/aKCVc6wzNzaar0TgCjIib67owmKeB7JzNaY0mwpHIKCHEH952W7vP33Qbis4cDWfOIeL/@HhKGq98T86dJ4cOiMH/oeHh9DZjHrqXgpI@r17NSDx/msnVq/uNCs0UASDRUzZ3mnWsxKaCymg/xq6pb7ktYAI7/pGU4ifgexyBmJPNQHCz1n1tFo9I8On3AqGNprRMfyf@Qb/TRCqoeh0BtcpgSUbGs8@bYYmblA@PQOnTxmIfOEfZMuo9b/C3/xv6//kBUuyRKOVTJxfbifoSuIvmTy/PL/0n/VkIuFbEtvwQwewY5TzyzoaKdA5mBqJZCt5ecnd4JlIbnOAdUhmu05xF@FgIImFSVKy/JH4r/uGpP2rGa8Cy83F@nyG@lFMrDJ9saWn2ZxlgN50gm@14AK1fkH7JpJV@lDnZqehtv70R/Q9np0kBcrnqlV1i3GLltOq1VxgK5aq1VJg2UwkytevemZHLYDok8slk9UqWHYCsBmwQtwGe5diNdaEZ@vuXZ5ISbu4CGBmc4VUBrdSVatBSnlI1vD0rk@jzw8O6VM2QGryMfyGFCcliQx9CAs/thgXK@Ldu4megfvrezu7ybt3tXLm4iJ0GY/BSV1yard7pttuo3v24kJsi7QFp5wHe6Z0caFmyik1nnTcxFP8SicklZBUdkerU6ploPFargjefgby29uFXL1eyIFLoRRP4nI@J/GQ37gYr4qxcyqDWipyCihW0Tm6NQn6sodD4/lljCqU5fLJBBDSJHCNlzH8uUhz@QiVzycBM5ciD6mWyzxokuUKiVKq7P9qG0lWB7aI/5C3y6ZyW8Wte8Al48@brbqQJlfPjZp6WTs3Kjihf1nt@t87R3Uwxt272TKgqJSpNoV2@8Hu8W67XYOxDFkreKAjUXcBteS48Ur1HtWrWsozqEDuKMVhSGAlwLKibeXVEmJFMPuo3glwIHDJbINtCBq98SGUOao2wBEkHkitBxfrsQ4b4MUGKCgyk1l0MYtxf3p2u2Egh1@@b2iluCRLBi5GeAl@t8vyNgmj9rPHu3v7x2ltW2Ix7eHuXlp7/uJ@TEVrfmEn7yzaj/Z3Hxy@gAjPHu/vPt//6OCT/RfPwN1jZ4sroPL@c/GOmlbYz9inwmv3rW4YujE1jPbZdHr2hr02zbYJtWdNoVDOwGWe0YayjPVFuapwd01Pf/1ad8d0sfc//Pb7H/5373/nu@9/59vvf@f7P/3i@9@G@8dwf5e/v/tvynl8/vSLf/a773/7d8DxP8D9R3D/5Kdf/MY3@E32P4b7P0Xc/ti/I@H4LQCsX/npF9/70U@/@NUfwP0v/fsH1@9f@8nq@/vfWn9jvO/97s1hvvtv4f49DisI@93f5m74vhb@t3m4X/3B@3/x7/j/T/0fGn/n/b/4Y3z4ln/6gz/9T@@/@e81rfSn//r9t773/lvffP@t77z/1j/W3v/Gv1Yz0cfvvv/@H/zVH/7eX/3h/0j/H9Pz9z7k//4H//Qv/te/@N//4g/9@ydw/zsw/eQv/j10lb/9gx/i/3t/8Ld/9EP8/8//6m//4Nf/9lf@JzL8Jjf8P//y3/DnX//af/yb3/rOX/3kG3/z6z/5m9/8g7/6P371//qN//jX//3v//U/@SY6/uZP/uqPfuUvv/ntv/zWP//Lb36x5vntG59ffID7F/8ALh@ezw@B8yHl@rIuX/xc@fn7YGORCrQTaN2//P43fgka@L9g7P23f4wnJ@Fe8/@xplKYH3Pb/wcM2vUyo08GTHD/@vtvfxdR9D8AiuAf4us7oWXJh1u@s7AAWn9rRaRf/ukX//xHZIsZlTqtEOFgXdJKqS0QaLbKZX/A9hePIMovLUMLAfgpfQcp1JLfd5C2vf/hN97/6B@//@Fvvv/hr@BoLeXK6d20pN6y8gYB8x8QDgMWPiQcBvwM0m@naBZOSn0Gto3P8qWsbdvVzz77TGhfKHhE994F@wx@7LPgYtwLj/D6XoEfuuOZXgbujVevWrhcG3FTVA5c0fjb98Ld9JCSpN1J7Siqxr2MC2WTx2JVcMiWss1I1pV@f6sCPwaPSmXrPC3tNIHpo6iXghEUSfWhbihM1dPZrawOAZUcD8cq9r1MLlXc0nUQgVMIN0U8z1bAg@WzbJbyk5wxvnSF7hBotkXGGT7JFb1nAj7oX2SsxLKM2fxfFViK5rP5qkpqYSSDH89PghuFPCSTmoULZsQUMs6VbXEXWgundHNlhiWYzVIzkLbBACmkwOs@8P21Wgoj1ngWwcoLUy8xykoqVYNyY2weJ90uIYjZfYICMWupI9beqs14xBTCqwfoSAnodCSqmpgq1R5AgrXZA4awEDiBffWqVi/VZnUE945jJzVL3ac8IbBaalZ/B/YawYR4QuzBO8hKqZZK1UuYIBaSV0@6zSspT4WjsqdYyq8DeOORhp17jN0R1ZLIF0I2EGE8ND5Ti9AYEIKDfzO15ReH/oGR7i1C@AYl5afCuP8O8cQ7nE3GAABXkmRZZnDjHoMddg@8ZxxUipKFV4pDSFGLoBYQOjCciEoJKarfFFkg/Vht60tfCAwLs7m5KcTqYlY8lAl1isLckwqd78AtjyjHVJhYKIvobNBhlyAvEL9K6W/GcfEwzjhgdifF73v3ttgdKCa9F24Ck1JZJ@fEOJTtVErUAH7dSQkvQf4RoJ0SoAtBntVosTIlpNOMybUY@rHDw0M/E@TwsiakoJlrWRXtuGQ2nU5jEEOW03I67b9lepOD7Btk8vXf8iYi98w1JwbTtFwVxLQqQycWlalUkLXR8d27d1ArtIescgBSLvO3k2m5EnmCA9eQZFnz4FSUlisLfAqAqYUcYwma/YUryfD4TwIaUlLgZw94NoIrEddKpTiFBPzLia1gf2FBRQrAz1nRgVmWLy5ZITdRK04L8rniWB1LFlxcWC3lk4Hn3iHbO3zyZP/p8bjVYgJ@LnU6Mdpj1@kanpdAv92nD/gxFa1cSMYaDcTKcUVDiiTsVzLYUFMHD44OnlcYx5JfZwkqR5UWm328lFUhNh5/uh3zt2OJ@M1LR3yOz8oCFQmtDNQyGasLsa6BIhDuIkDRvMqqwhNvcN@ZsUQmLYpptYAiaBLXTCEfv@hMGWpk5uqboBPi4RV5e5swINTPJVqGQSNUb0Go1/2NjEwV6s/3jyHC8SFTtYws1D9jMxkTlC6FulWzDHswGW7ijkCxmREjZdpsZNL407JZeKq5QlrNF1sbG9a5hGk2qZbPcWvnJVjPJSzGV@FiwlcF9lVwggvSwP2azN8se3BY9Xcsou7DBN@2KKp56JdJASflOThhHL2q0B2WF7WE2Mbnn09YvQ6Sv3TwUIgBeRmyYNOeZPbkoUzV3Ju6BvkOGOuZn5j4MVO5Z3pjS59DXwNsxC4vL/sA6eAh0@oaWXmMHj4vu@TSAfPlTBdidqVSe6fmisLRbqXyLqtpAjgIWwruCtyABkCbK7YU/qt6kEg2W1KAtKmiCK9sNitQ8xUqhsBoA827TK0m8TaYzam0f0bA7@Pos9piRdwPO7uzCJvN8LDoAx5sMHFZJvArcj/fVhDIBkjDLYP0Nfaq35szd@9mcXolm8uE8yhUYnYJdbOZzWUR43gkqxXLFf0FH1EUWzHBMiasVwNzrAkPPlWoqTGRoQ2pTLaUEWKNWEP4//vlr2ltj@vZjLqtjMGogzG3rehg7IAxv610wGiCsbytmGCc1rNqZluZ1gUmbHO1yQy1MtXEiTFDLe3cTax7htWX8aRWTaQENHHb/wxBPYhY79V6TneKm2SqPdm0bcNFHQo8Qi4nVh0bFXrWULUPaZ1gieS5MKidkaYHwagNZNQR5dq6JfTkjtOby95kbuGZJ8txa3FgbOOBxwK6ARwPTuftZLO5SoO15LEz3hG0fDHVUDMwVOGtltJaesPYKRYrPblrGbq7k6/kS@keHqfyF/p28pnKQP7syeNHk8n4yKAzVju5MkRArYqo/2ynVMnnW42GKKYalEwLvyDP6Zq0sQHEwNB7ErxxGdCTtFILIvdMt1aLx3eyqiaplWymdCksEIc4xxLWBYyawpKlEe/nPumo2I4NVKqS1tPmOWGh0u/3L7fOUwuLoJ9L3Ab4uZT0dOc8tFalSLgKm6Ylc@EJLnof0H3ur3BWRC1fEquN6sJeLIjV1qVwb2T0TB2PVjUz59djFYCac6gxSKjJhMuK6ziTSsfoO66xCJhVC0FAnqHrAXLiZZhcM4Mpnl9PrhAJNDu/DiWXFy/DWEG2hMtLwDtHNqDd14ldpy3IDbWca@0D7YLmsx2oy8ZgsZcvhdjW0SfZeh2q@jxX1HL5XF7LFgr5ogYDVTlXAPEuo2YKmbymAZRcuVQuXkK7VpR3MfoaJts7D9p7hb4HktArXKFto8WS756a1nkpK/F8JJLVy8vYOyF25@gTDUbWtVcCRutPNKley@bLYMqiSctChpmgaZKWlbKqpGbxf4tBw/@Hh9fgr@ETYmU14Ri1XD2F8RZ4BJs9Rm05E4cdO/i9tAG7b3TXhNgb6rQ/fM91PO/vEea@bp9wrwcmVy0dej3S8aOR3sicDNeEeDEeoYIsw/0Hg7A/6kAGkRzyAPfh4VqOsypAkb14tqaUT8KPOQAy@NccIPjRwUePjiPv4/3dvUdCgd0/fPrgyivvB8qzx/sPj0NrkfsGUfMhiF/cf/z4qtV/5Q5fHPWnjou38PDwRW7xCJ3w@LGQg2s5UOhMQPwHWokjBVYERL58MTCoAh5auQti@F3fmC8sjBk0fsrPVpteeIiCH7OvCMfBgWudIaXtGKzL9aDhvADpKPVlBrVYFoQxs50zVsywnmNZusucfn8DHIc6Hh41kBO2LGyJmPSZ41q9M7NnbAhP8JxqGQSKPmVCeARARtMuqdgALgg1XsOoZjNcaetYU4NNx2ytI7zQCY2uORjCGHzmBAGEjq4zuL/sBfGN6DW52WHC0yC3az7W9eACSI@lvCjuieIjfaJXXaP4suplKpVn7hiGY90bGPszaLHsBfQg3Z2nS@msOJHFwkMmt2Mvt7StAa7fWM4YBRhv3ACOfydXarR2mn/9Wz/@uz/59UENqE0zs5fJ4@zT9s6TxzlnMq54c71i92pK9aRSr8alOEg5@QoQPmCOGfG/Po8sk7SklUv5UjmrldKlcimXVwv5fFrV0iCZFssga2TUkloo5ctqupQrA4@SK4Nvvlz0OWwlYKmVrQqAtbvWtGdsk8AlD0Gy4uuu7G1CT7KYHtqnTDQgjiigMDyhY/pbZg2GV6ZmWLbIAKLOuiz28OFe5uFDUbyPFty3spcRxR5a8qVMpnhfFA3y2SshvyU6PE4JtYyKE27JZO5DBUw5APxAhygO0bJfwOlEUTTRsrf78CGm00eLhvEh2An34RYrsBQhmI0WYPwJwJsQGgTb5enkKKP7aMEk0ech99kDP1H8KMgO@hzxYBzAo6Cku7uieMAtu7vos0fFzvOMfg0tu3SJogsW6BiiOADDwIUuKYodMGL3EMUumLpzHdxGYMJvONgTXRTnHD2IIFGcUWi9eyKK7cAdk/nEz00esVshi8pLfY8sZfyJohZkGoNlQ0tWFHOhJQdle/ToE3046RkDfs1d/u5CSR89yurmbLr/sPPRR53BoOPOd/c/OkKvvb1HwKvMp25n0PEjdtpwORBr75Gmn4zmVy8o9UG7XdGtlV5fa7dzun3Fqz1vG5hDiPUGcuZfA0xo1N4Dr71H7Xv6qnVzAthGyjCCdwev@yN439c73Cu4yIves05HrGLzV5RmQkBpAhfAsTueAKW10yO96zpVtM9qLJNGhmbeKGRaVfJgI5AKMtVL9O8n8KnjHFTyfN6Y1TKt2qxW1PjGq35CbM60vCmmN0Y7ajlf2dB3VC2XmlVQU4jTj7O4pO6whHp36y1LPE3uaCAhiM2dHUlsqK0dTS1VCsWXW1NRTFbwuZMtVt4mMvEMY/hINoqtnWI@EqNYTOmKVikWgU8DnExguO/gTE87kTgz9JNkEnNL8w5QBCorm1M5zWo/MUvPajxfbJ6szmpqlesuZ5lrwHr4oYxpd@K4HOQAwM12MhXcbJEQ1XJJhAwoSiKZDImeAqbFLtlPv358cnz8GTGEdX9K5JlrIPWq@taPHu3JB4eBDT9xIT9EPtVx5T2kWks@nGENnI5BQpEfwRAL0l7ghicyXceS92l3ITC7gUegZUv21U3Lx4@W4DwfOmc8ZVRoUSWdpXbXYPgFELPH9FodTHqPJShXTE@e0eDertdr7dqIdD5AEYNYX2P0eYwFmAOP5z1Us0HRz/GUou/RrmUuq53aLDYDOO0ak9RXI6f3Skt1qz388Mf92n2MXG3Du1M1aobrOq4IsrZY7e/Ytant6X3jmeGiApmDw01gNfDoYqLPjOQma@5j6D2UYy6lusvsRc6eTkcJXap3kstOON0XOiByEl8PCn1Op2nbNVG8rPZrLPESgr4Bu7vJEj35fnInVwU83WftJDhlXvVf9ZnGCrkqySEJhAVdifCD5dZZslb/Grw47JNKBXLjV/QJQMXEALDZIw8IPTYvq92axRISm7EkISlXHdQaGP0CH9uSKLYkqXHREuqS9KlQh/5ancf0mjft0DejWKajaplCdQZuajFXHUL16i9nVbc2nrpG1QKrP0vIDw7rVUAq4A7AvL1IvP@lbyS3pXyNu1UJ1AXODrXldm1WtVELLTSMWrYGHqlGLpMGCR8exTSM@VohrRbS2XQuLRXRFQb8dD4NjiABAeORsBIiY2I6M8vIalo11HQi88rsvUqmTxLA0hDSWDI9cfbt6YiBC1QVtk2ywhvQk9K2LJDMeg7TtyVqrEAyqlgwwPqQjc30EEEdGbpFMZJJiWW3EtZmAsNsHk/H@41WpbI/G38dvBLSm51CqphJvU0mq4mNZM0z3gj1qlBH8kKlHm9Ay/UnUJk3HTWglsGkFrVKo9HBIhYz6WwmC6Uz2xeDbbEuttKZjYIKVXTJiGwwTjeic4rI8Szcxm3kzC0Dqk4ta1VBpgm@bEmTykp@K5/hk4w8pjD2yRtikiWaYnBIPhGPF7V4PBmv4nrIhujPZwNNI3oWB@oav6vuiMCMiRWxrGGABWmkc9CZIHfAjl0KyC2yHAi@58Ll@eV2XfiK8BxPt25rL/FXfPlk9xB/XwGnMlhLL5@8OHxx@FBgCu1tBfazulGVq@0qWCS5fk@IVRgDStr0NXgpG4x92V2zqe36S/5u4gELgCuQZvkGa9FuNsNEqY59gtohdlgcyqC7o4amZVsNrQhjH1DTIKimqVVcLYrhEQ65DpUxO4f8bafqeLDya2w@11NSMBVwl7FBarPCTwhqc20LvzwvsdjpyUa9vJWKP6tkU/EH8WwudgqVsllPqfN4aiuF67hKSs2csI3SViqf37qT3YofpSqlQbqipvCpwbMSZ9JG7F47jSt7ZS8pUC2w2JXpiN3a7uBot8rqJW2uVHf3qrGXbbFUzPLDinUtRQc62WZwLrSOWspe4mx7U8Bd/vHYeZzF4pfwE2L36Gipxo@Wslh4uBSXvv0FoWyuwJKxctK3FcsxLxGuxnwlfi8Wx0WPiue9i1HDCU7ufe2VBm02ZjuBA4h0ON0GY2o@jysDMeXV2PtcK2WfHBzaD9yHhhBrblxsOLhOwxb7Gt/ZH3@dsTEgNc6atdislvO30qv1uqRua6hMr8gqMGz01YKUuajzjlEnj4IGPu9/6Qe52XYJ7FpGBbum5VNava5uaVCw8fsvfh/VIp3vf7L7mMVxdv/v/uRHWvHv/uRf0U69@CXN@GvZYgxColEtFGPn5@Pz80u4uF8@1opd26DQAvwoql4ubslQGqWkg6GtxDgegVEqqsmYJ8X87ZiFvJRIqIqW3MqWMknwufDVniW0TAmswaIXOYmFvJiM7R@ZeU29t70DJdvJ5rTqBtSlGh4TZuFv2/DKKEA@eXXBGFi69d5gYGpkUhRWeSdtv2PSNnuH603vpA32qlbHDRYqHi4O1mO28LAlLmLG6yllK85AwGL1xmX1spWiBR0SVF9u2c0reGhu4CGZZactG37Glkc/wyArOXhgDWzG1mtPTGwlFaXXE69Py20bLF@HprKlLI5As61gmYb/JKmZfP9Lv6Fphb/7k1@7aF@0P9NASC2XC6oW@9nPtqf21DN69Z8BgBuU4QSCJvGaqLUGDaGAyrhmW9OPFRrkLsjGUxuZcR4@EFdRQGXAyJgD2@iRuCqcIvNFNdvm@hh7CQq2hboy0sTMk/6zZFUQAq6XM@vuoJsmGGwL1TE3WknhXPgqesHYzoDhrwpfXYAChxGM5k637VlTd0yHjBIUT22l2V2IAil8FXVdbpCOD39gkIBCKlvXo/Ise4Q1YtTYyPA81JwJY5rwVYji66y35mysozoaDGnaMBLJGITySR69BqTdgrQtHqFNrgkqPQ@QZjx3PJINDL3wVeBNCAsmsCzM3IYAVSArXwUEQBkSPmCzxbZZNsnOzVSqulDLeYmHG1ARqR6owhAwGkLroeqVIHIVw4ETCBL4lWRsF34NA8cYcQyAcBh8i0INRBGMTjbkAklXzQeDAlikFy5BRWN37y5yVauZvSSjEiH8E3OM02xUD/bqvAKwQIy706uIaYYKT6uBa9jsAOMpyi60OolrOq1GojIRrZeCAP8PbrTYIq9UFXlUsQB@ffFe0QWUQWREO6/DLtuuMVUrJlmY@S7kvUuZIoUEoWzanN2Rtc8Cz0vI4c9iwTfIgGgdR6cu/XZ7VRcKA859ih@AQo14nBj4Oky4zjskfgeTIHYYC4piWhS6b7ogNdHeiUDdZiKrJjHaQj0p5YOOH2g5hqcA8kl8USwMzeCto9pIP50NUnfVdaBCvbFjk55J0oOFRzCgRQCN8lX08WxP7TP8YKBfNxQ5miOP1PNhy8cck95MBxUKUVzci9BxQboOcJNmxkBm3VGPaWWWoIZGqgTtEFySIlGGO8B8I447ljGCLD03DDrq51UUZQAM2bRD@hSfmNCuhg9NGIFsT3nAEaycmSemcoyauyWnjycCuXaaGPJw2P34tgdfd6HlOCfMMk8MPiOdWNLt4zEQP4CDTgNmFzcgtoIbcLRsGmdB1DQPBXcRXkVuLKUjcTcS8@T1d1bdSLSxRi9ovDGhVizjVLcj@KXrQvDlbm/uBdrBSMcV2OWQ5Bq@XqBaHDV@hAqvBF/PWY1UbMm40jFOiDEx0A@GRmHsGqcMJWgBxxggmt1A0w72YijtV2kAoL4HPQvVhk7cCuqHgpy4vUQXup5P4G12h2U1AQNy5W2@ojWAgVVfW4YOfhAVy@FNelAxMk3vI12B3jnqgR9qJvGbH8YPWjeaSaXronmzDR8cDjqUVo3xbhFY8hEL9g5sz1T0DfAsQA5X5GQjIaYAbEpMihx0GP9qdN7aBaIlFXYdUpohBB/VAIVYBR1JDuqFjHzZTwCP@7rHP//iKxU9OzuTSdPt1DVlw8Ov3XmOrVvKeGACR@woE2M09r8rbnaVcQB3YZL4Ry7l8XC8M0O@tla@O@dvQeh7NX9XUiLe9@I4OJ7ix9wGI9KKh@roPGpQD036EGQ34W@S4u1Pa6XPg/ZXwfYnleKXCIQxBDNLz9PdNABLd7on6f5Zr@p7nFKHBOBQi0bgiPqn3cAy8gKTOe6HIZwJ0tHQq2Od0HoxQBL5dPEiaV7CIOQ8sPr2sTmDSLZxxnZdV58nyD@JobEBJ@bE9rA5DPvkA0ZUjX/OlSGbs8a8tRR9FkaHQS3cLeGiyjvh/GagXDM2@s@4/wz8Z9x/tkg0SLYxa3GWDJ0usTjY6lFTahASwcyDMJdci/TChyADP85UDgJDzpfcLuHu1ih2gG9ug3qsBQ0D2sQYEG4klMbLZqPZsj3jbKuVUgbQ2EVCBNQ4gG60CKdnvdCM2LdOrbHjLTnZqCAXRiU/3@jUHfqtgbcVLGNYQdQwOL5M1Gk6GPnbOjhD4BcYICAfBp7IGuxOEmayGqpiJ09oOA1xgWOesYafmRZxX76X7wbsEkc9R2wUUCsCCN3DIkE2wYcFPYd/2zSgDp@6DoQJwkr0OcYR6taLt@KAyStdhdOaKlVSJFeSFGQT0I7sau1qUQJ/qIrGFa9IMS/9@o9mf@NLZ78P/WJ17qnB8gGjKkS7Cm7BBBbC7y6EVVavReoVcqBs6Zbhwsi1z/lTf7SGZLaUQMzg6WARvDNz0h0mIpXfTfL6oSOooi1WwqYwr9WgiPMa75a8XwQo5QgPo3l@tHnQEPz4nIAAjMzKaIYfbRaNNqvVOOFgszXRziKZnFEmZzwKDz1bk8mWHw2kp4NgeMHqaQF3intERYCn8mEU2KCxyDz91MDF99eo9xOXKPw0FzSHWoHfhpDFxnbWba1MvRHJdIRoXQGADfEagB7/THpFuErwVCm0hTSKozKgUdzmNwNOK6CBEQmuct3YibCRkQwMDL@YonEA@q6YagiiStPM@MvwW0wHjsGtXnfMLIdUlx0z6Su/fxDHFmI20kEj3IeaySFBRknmhe0rlY3yHDG2OwUBB7i6zpnDEiuYbXBXpn5UpWM5HWWk4yYa/Hgyd5XH82QgP@BCDbs3dib6xMnlKlxoMqnZrUqfywzmwHbwm2sR/fjA6/Ucw7PjE6jUrjOwTc9IM1RdemL4YofhfwFEiPLJvtHxBMHfzsXFWATN2xWyuu22aZuT9v/b3fe2tZEre77Gn0IxZOhO2v9IIImJmRgwic8kkAskOVnCeBq7DZ4Y2@M2fzxJznPvfbFfYPf9foT9Kvc73Ff7Kc7Wr0pSq21jyMzZPftsnhnc3ZJKpVKpVJJKVQ0PVpJ@2dqKs9Ek2HN5OYP1Lz055Uk8aaB7A69/8mvUHPm3w0SwB13ssNP87O0NdCL8blQVybAm6f@UekYajIr7ycqRHclDlT4ZeRz15Kx/3j8lre8izmMfNjMBvp7ABkLhYMC4BCrEkrbshPzgUeI1g9DXRX/67qLqpxUv9G35lTSAFDECNZykMSg7nFFd48bqpJip7@D78T1w8T2Yjy@vwidxlqV5RRK/r@pHXgKBMiZoPLodDTSd5FZrCp0UKvYz9CopcGcUW2yk1gKmVcpa1dnzbeKPwL7F9GYRf38T/ed3oCleu2v3hTTs1cGY5M057D09DpMZm/NWj7LXfcie6eosa2/fsS7KiwjFO1AhSI1lwdWDD2wamIhpFNsNZAP4Fp6HXdgU37OxWEUSZ@A0vAzU55Wbu2i70Yq64ThqeTpn4MA1Ld6nBRvLq7s1HIKOhV5f1noezV2@TaVpHESXTOUbWCYMLn3/ZraSLB3LPbxTzhjWb6Yf0qdEM7b4KrJbTeuA5eVFbMdedrD9iVhOEmahKzEStRyV@Ud6Em40bicI0UFmz1KQVOvPE5/7nm3SHWYEmzefbjK8oBuIcGg13YffR6LbW0qd6xSqmF7OpAMMze7xzrwed7jC8KQcO92NJW9jujvznMNqAiwRYVvfN4VMQYaRSLPpuRDly9we6/emZAK@8T5d74ZZpTFDoNqSLOlGHV5us37hZ7AyrtMvNpze0y8AnkajhjCUaRv2tHTYYcUp5@HA0Vr0F1LSCYpDRSG5RsPJlTHPlP3LN1tn88Y6m1N1NlN12hGQrtLJlGmmqtS9gO6Z1wXdqD26QTojCWtn@pkntulfrx8OsVvxZbmzXO4EavlyuUwCeTlaLtc8EsrLreXyNj/Ey@UDfvi8XP6JHpKxtfx1uWyGBTIM6ZUfXuC7FuF4by6Xtzz/W2YUfo5iU29@uWz7lPL8KK9MESIF2k1aI47Yen3dzNEwoomNlcpAgWPiAMsn3ocJ@P8i/SchwziYEBKxx/mAM6uHqpSaNJwZQ@qhacMEq5gxkst6Nq/t7bCRlc2Cah7SGs8tw@BJDV9cTgsjQQypfKJBv4Qg5GZ5NkbKmcnuiI6unTiUOzldv8QSZH2g5XH6EWU@TirhOHG6vOmvNAjpwLvhicI34TmFjqmOMcKZrD8DLRD1l@U5jUJfp3HRve/2EO91pzMRtjmTRXqJwToynXQ4PpzjaIz9QZpJOBWm/h23DG/KyaAE904UY6mgR@YNyfxZtwyCwR38/rzmOOWAWkoEIfGoeCyjzM4LLIuRlMg6R1OVwUcoODKHRnjU/Mwx@Lb1I@cTcRPwXHHTNGTKSpUsudJikgrn4RbsIhxJ7XbxWoOzsO9bvpqS19hr8QDAKWlrEfna/w79vS/6u1GoDREmKpilWM@eSqfV67mz7ATm3aTa6Q5EYqC2/ZnKka0hITmtDhzNfB6vTan4MPkQJV8qtdAntH1DNrsmuIVuk2sLgQUtYXiZ/vh5hT5@XrmZUNMaSfcyb5SWPGrScKThFtOkafNxlYbP6mKk8P522P3uDh6mO9jtPMDjBgwnSC6jfHjRYyuXZGyT2JYvEKmlshJBzseltpuTjyTu@ejWHtvSh73G/vbe7uuPNOk@efLE13P0OMEPoxZ7rXYeF8hssW3ngxnLlpUAgbJw2I3t@PisPxzd@9TLTskSEdakDIRUi2E/PcZ9LcsceT4xdqmc5HUoqmF9ToZBmJJKUHVCTNkdTdcRESQaeQ9CDcSot0TvgFdrPoeEajR64XnUaPD0ZUKm61kMXWNOxP2/L94rXMRDDg0u8cyuMhl2m6G299SHV9VDdfiqpnbebf2kPu69Ux@qu4dwgPD23ebr@pai/2u7BzWVSZniIfYjFpRE1@2oGSGir1opFh8rhrzVH4xF7nhbvnw/CM/Vq34zwjHV8zg8f3EmL/leNNqQUjVajo6xh9nhWJ/nnRHsLTg4JS1jody0@HoirhgoyntCa9pzrHnP@61Ou0N5M1j7DjpRbG60qW6HepDkrbnUHYiShDiUbDrE8WVhgXVFxUPKj7MbAhOK/RVIjBwSuLKVV5pw9t93U/Cwtv/mQMGXxtbe7nb9sL63e6B29vbp9e3H@u5Lomf94HC/vvkOSZzxzd52fae@VeUPgkAxr@Dk4teLeDQXhTyyM1Wan3HynR9Q99u39K43NHh1FfJFzVgtX/QgfTpht/N71Fpez1zEUF9wOZSPCpS3VN1/@Z7mfBX9hhNOcxTM9gfZdzHHRl0qqudcGw2WDRpv63q40rSXK/l8HnE@VgiPFK2z8wuPnwNlgLMRT6sTqewWbFSw9y0@MngsG9BU0T2CDVDGYKWiOKzZ8nLwnEFuUG3Nbh@uVqU2MSLULyj6wpiarGeYYtpWBkBxiaLew35Qad1@IL6nDyu62tFQMqhH9oNkUI/lA1TROmxH1KrOcTHau4B4Vmvy4dfzwQ4fC6sn9sNmyKvYpxon6Tfu0lDZsJDwGNLl4HWyy8MBdsUBDIrEnB@B3bpdGRiRhBQlmShHiWzbRjmzJGzaOGrQZm8SqhupxA2wEwrbo1h5FT@vDmEcFPU6EjbwtBv2xAQqMd1h3lNP4c2pou@Bd2y4Pb6WMugzAyLUZxoPW25ba4XRXctRyc2pGkNtI8khb40J2m0IbE4h8EfAEKBcaqXT5JmK784CTL@tWdmL@8SR2Lf9m5uf2Ll10YxSBbTVlvdr5/fffU3kILVOMnaKjB110e/RkNRKPsps94c0xlmscoAySMHmWX8w6kgfeukW8IkTT3OUGxMb1fZLZSNVG@gwWWOv33MqPSEuvqHWE2LKu9TKHC9n51Z8JZGrifNpEha7O6ATnvQvI@fsLMAh0lWE7RdShPmsHJuf4xFjIvpnJpEdf1MIePu0srG9@Sn3t18CRL0VsSBBp43RIf4nxkRdNDz4nI8NFofQu/RIM9EK44sTlNY2eFpaYpQbYLQOPOvQuu5FY92mibnx9Hdc2Zn8zh@/fq1IqRwkk45UHp95iXQL1JGpMuAyx0qbgDiyk5AlWe@ZLwHDtPL6Ba7poBfgbagHOYJ1@0QsQC1CTOtOLtokWXRIZt3dFr6vNtiiIolnj@s3bn8UfvY2Kw83/EJiUKIccnpGRAcGcsn3HbMUnq@mwG3PB0fy@@7gns7FTqaH74K2PRfad@GWe3gzLJmWHFh3B/u3OWBlcvtDYKntwc2AZZKchmY53TJnsLRorWnn1/jLVN/x2CMwmHuxg2KBOrVd9PiI2jgu96SA74JJFKKDw@3a/r7KyvqEypLcw5KhpcUgYN9TbxNr206PhV3eKk12sWyVJ/MlZdFm/s0bzDOJd4Oo0DpIoOlhhUXiHr3duRapp2cWViHY@p4FoqFcGrsvRgbFRxrwN1oDErJJpzkNzMxs5qJMPp3YNQLXdAtEN3Zt@NnCWuZuBDoejl1Ark1QeIqbJbP774Pox2VTjyhY8LSEBrdIk6b5htYJB1TxgDLm8@kenNMtpkthZC8K9qKhHQy/imkN@88zFDOSKOGiCztiXSvHGjXRj5eMmsMGiZgGQlh66kSxaKYEI@L5y3O3Q/1k0vPSUxApmQh9@8LlCip@/E1PYUwNO09WrELujrUlxubIYHmM3VkNe/3mTPdhC702KR4mqyJpO7eq3D@mKpklUjUZms9sjEkkyGurq49ugz3ZClM892dhyxwyKT9H5wNa3ycg43HM2/vEufXdwKQnDDCHdGJabwbMREFSdWbMKam282Tk4ke4yL4QIQPn/4gmPFmrr64ncJsNXWYkFzpnmWqDM4RtQ2XUTFH/2/zqIJBvre/e99cngw2ZYDr4DVb5b/rDOEpu5Tl@Y5xPuG@f/hYNhz3OJveZzgHF42tMcy/b8W07MXiVViGRz9vclrT17SQxuw3MXgNXwtuLeQQQx@7e@uT2Xq607jZ1p/66ph6wj812ai8yO8z6juy51@nNQ4BlMO9LYPrgO3z34zL9TzgEBiSRiW/zeUwb/1bcmCKkNR9xOChtFqpla2my99txM@zB00iQvR@rbPADFeRd2Nrejj9rZ724nipPyMWDnkelgmwun@Wi9A0buoCUBiG9ie/OhIWbGsZSEtdrTvuwj8LBVnQtu2dsORkWSk@La88y3LpeMArOj54dBw@alayiyTfsnccXw6vW59P@2WVbddXg15Pr5vj335RafQzP2WrlB/GMXFqrFNi37BMFp9rPisy5GsEf2cszAlrnJdKvUssqWYev31M@P/CiuYwbEhNcqh6cGy7EFbtR5fxo7bjSqxTXz496x@u45Dd6WBk9LD308OEHmkVJxsjJ/NHoGHOqu@sa9S4V3IlyRFl9NUTx1RD68iYcdvqvq7svU7txUACwBaZtvXlDXYKHL8CaDXdP8r3oytPbZIECx2agIGUW@FZQCffceT8Z2zGtDmFGvRKQNhtf89@xn1ko5i8Goz6nGB@QYC31tfM1s2CuMRV5R4GyHHWMp0jcLyA4SR4PB0PydSxW1LmSqGsl3J30HRBHKMniMPspm8WdQiCq73IdHWfifBQ2z4BEl9Tqr1xMPX@u8EasFud5Fw@mHOGQL0wUj/GIAxD6GfBpA6pgzT3max8Zaj7eS3iQL7xHNeJ7Mmwgn2FNESkw/1Zf@H4Tl39OBBDCL4jOlddbnFrzIkVS7g7y5gIcrKUX/jhmwLVK6ZQFNBawpb5KApwtxZlGqFaTib4vXIGcQiv6p1uQK/HbVDNsfl@yM0n4nFq/xaAldyknbeCnmxTznGI5U8xkdkixcCs1sNNFy6M3EQ2rsdqKul1CWmixkJADj3y/V9f/0NYfH6HOY4u8pOem0nOp9LykC1JJrjxN8Emmspspu/glyfdNZZNswVRdFcXKS556upknlSTJuz4vb5wf9RudJPOG7UrhSpvwPJWQc1J@ntH7knIvVcYyuE0/knTN3yu65y2Wqbwv0vXjN6M7KGLjWW1rMsGl@V6n@2NGB1rXKWCzLFFTKSnOcS@VGVQVfQdTixPS4LDPz8N2o5JAeVgyEofHTHbj@YtsXisZP3qTaMgtxqmBNWOMOFTiOh8y4a75wiLVw8n3HBAME4ymzMjdMIXHuvDYAYtc90y1cgtyaoBT0yaHeAX3Ir/ijxnsaeRMvsXZiQuC@bU0Xm43pwnEQvdedjaZ0tIE10Xko27UnFkkqXs8CXG2kNh1doFtnZHcwW5jG/yelROuoDCSYoruNkVTOslQMux7Uxci8Vvm74UHmZch6diDbnStqlhmhHwLK5O64D6K4lEMX1PsBie@GAy6OHVkhe@Kr1BrZ/8rqzhuSSA6M3s@U4dlj@QP8KQvpFOhvNoD5CsYiCQJ8cXpKS6T4QZs/wqiFTsunVE@U@2NZUODxsyjFblmHik432AB3O2cukhIz8noAaXjQdiM8hnS0WLSfjLS1HZHh4vl/XTcG4FLM5rSypnMv1x0mp@3XuI890mp@KjkkOxSHwcX848eJxesiEgmYQVeCVdLjzMZ52y4KWfDOQAM1GtM9O@JN6PLqNeLMlWaMThjTEprHA0vo1Y@k9mP7CEw4IKVcTKJe9j9i2FTNndI6QqJGXFLOA7kOIw4DL@Yn@W4uMlnZUEGh1bJaTN19WWnBQKaGyftPk6H@cACbgKEHih0Ho2IKA98lUaJz541Lqy7nGMjiqgBPyfO2YQlQ68/6jSpZ3gnK9MlUHIMklTWa01gQvU1uyEuB@dnIYDrMQkFDALmKGkeDhl9aP5dOCjdMHPGHpqeKZD06/NYoeEeDTskfRMCc69wMQd36uDDV/UDdbC3c/ihul9T9Px2f@99fbu2rTY/8hk3DsrZ@696tfeapIs9TZdT8z36kK0eUMksJ2Squx9V7a9v92sHB2pvX9XfvH1dJ2gEfr@6e1ivHQSqvrv1@t02n74TBLW7d6he19/UDynb4V7AtZpimaSc2ttRb2r7W6/otbpZf10//Mg17tQPd1EZTvWr6m11/7C@9e51dV@9fbf/du@gptCwzHb9YOt1tf6mtp2n@qlOVXtf2z1UB6@qr19PNHTvw25tX7GRgNPKzRphWd2kJSxq4nZu1/drW4doUPK0RcQjBF8H6uBtbauOh9pfa9Sc6v7HQAM9qP3LO8pEiWq7@qb6khqX8W6hCvXL1rv9GtwngRIH7zYPDuuH7w5r6uXe3jbT@qC2/76@VTtYV5nXewdMsHcHtUAhMiVXTTCIWpROz5vvDupMt/ruIc0Z797C3sGnTv5AhCEsq1R0mwkMMwi0loi0t/8RUEEH7oBAfXhVo@/7oClTqwoqwKJi69DNRhUSEQ/dZqrd2svX9Ze13a0akvcA5kP9oOZTh9UPkKEOg4yPxDpU6TtuNfqJ8JJHYtaM4dyAu1PVd1R1@30dmOvcxAEHdc0tTLatV5rmefj/dTZROn3sGYTn7sZKe/rTZQSPl9M7MrP3aKzHpK297RrNyNrZVTZJeEezztMJV0puGs00NpFeUy5rWtHJxWmj02v3ccfUFpONj/P4NEAYJB8hYT5l5kQh0/srXGBxsdF4X23QQveg0fCDu5RMoXFbCb0NPi@Xr9uIyA9YeWPjp1wWuj9PEWrjB33QyYZ6OIBATqH@D2L6Fp5HvioUWpEuhsv7AGy2jmI5NjnDUQqJRr7siFg2SZW8M8HvHc0OXNAz4PPNBvZJYRnJmfox/el9TV5kcnA@kHSW7a5CAYtYRqPze2SqkUrYJQL/0R4JOm2uMh9H0edTr@hWhzV//rTfb3m@b8pw3hGtA089/5biJ9HpRPHcZHlGlo@dddCE2Ky7WYWx58@aZEr3S37ILfPwpzHiH99gIz4fsGvKVfFmtd609H6Q4rBICpR2bYHrFdzJ0PneVP9a/4DVXHHl8frE91f2u4wt2AvCNy5NeEdc7ph/Xh1LBhpg7IuDSNLRHjIKBaeMsTexma8o4xkyXXVasPyhufos4nmdSEKK7EXYdevEbDzsXLvYkxx@uV99s/luZ4dEJ7B9/HT1ydp6xrrd@msgvx9RD7uvZa9jA5rHSU/jJGeUbJHiwyPF8R6esD8zcKGAjPAabzqNP8LPg7XbSFsyQZChuTECO/VgopeNQIesYgcc9zKGX2eOTM0AXqqpPlpzHl6zih@SrsQ8oI1ZumPutWv8AWw7/M0Qtw3SDKRZjB36EufS6oLlXnbHmIry4oYd9yBLPmv4WNy4WRrwVhfbz@J2Lb9p3nZ6MRZTRoxX7nYuSUjcm8RCGbuKnozst@xnRG8As/cw@vJXzW/0@FE7uGN3d2E8qo4OiIw7tiT2qZPNaN3oIw35GFE84FTN1PRcYZff10jx2NPbydYxiDMaGBWEpIGNbxrwuvUjMlklW8C@WPbVF@FUOO8AnHXNsfqdOHdWczSUdeM/RL8brxRKYFknJ0K1K1tHxmT5aP1YGHKmyPSn6MHw/4k0mQH/Oa04CXpCLccJ4J0oyVCFVrR8ZaJ0rsxBg3O6kVDT/fQxAfPN7Zgz2zB9enMt92uIBLp3xubDR3Z72PZmEABMjo0Nd/xak7SzkJZOL7K@Lo5zkl7zfOApPVeYqWIKbm7tOGC1KzBnK3jxlS97TU6Fr6moeiELtxMe9bRkmljKq/txVsD5xv9H4QFvgNgBz1x6Jlark5xV1KPMyAHtasmZcFrWYxKppd9uPLV7oBwXmSnZr0@@DKEI9AbwmW4nhzPpKzHPTXtc5JlYHbIXPDgpxzIZk492WXfChpjdCHDut3gzBBFPRleYILoCnV31JdCUd58NRVBJYnWY@BmEuPXzRFqeVq8s9rwzCQ612L/riX/8SHa1TI68OPjQGLrX5fPqTTgmlLt3a7awWOHBQT@A7SIqk20JXR7RXZr9/pBUxxDtJhyDztjPqw960yHqxRdD7b@Q5rPOUO9IGKWfqoHaJKt3nmbEMT2jFndGuK3QyjN/cJPOI1iIinuS69ya8oh5DY9umE3HzvXDkvKeJynPiSbslpSJ@Fytqa9fJZcQVLsMjZiCndguLthmk@vBuYMdflf94WfM/VCBeq2oZT2TOiB5L1A6qd5jH4/NkTR90I95R4O6AjsglhIl2Uizhqo0Rz/R7KTtmrKJd0z4LuWWfH89lkmNtRRVlDCurp2Yby1HnQkqrWjXoNZZaGlllVGZteD6duNijL2Fpo@tVfZTz4qUsigRlftGdcSTyE379BFPepO/cj/G6KEvOOPWKigQhs6Kc9VpOcf4wabgQycattw9UdJkWuEA22@89On3mBfN1qF2@9cMR3E0phVAs9C5LjCMhveX/lmvsdXvhqedfiekdRq8yl@LxMPjmB/RYafD/lXMgYskGqOTqTVOnsW/jLhhw7s9l1x3XHPFo2jguWYKo@G4eiZuInjnHEaASbRV5u/BpI80W@bxalIok75/yvZ4JX/9xrKPSrMKy4k@AGgBtzFhQSF3SEd8Mcm5fLo@leFkXgYHxxOVU6F/g8VeCuNnRCI@hklhbJCZMktwG4GV2Y0YH7Wugxb7IBzC0VK0HSHMTuzx5yBExGuSIj/CUqCsSk@LTlE5RbmGH0I8jG8m98qTfzL2hMCfQL/0aBa3zGIEFnFt420plvWK9jJKuLB5YIdlNEtikmKd007PuX7IMS2uJ6Gmk8c3UYMtf0gp0m72prgSI9KjhQ/i63kNEjmNsY9JZVkt@@y3AypIdeQVb2bY6Db7WR78OMSVnTMIpi0N2XOQvolUTaISQgRPmNe6KItP5dtHzMrKXXttgoCVWSZnTmxrL2s0F76B0pH5Fcda/SEJ4@wE9bSpx3I86g@W70i9G2XHTM9ss2jd9P1bDYGF2So0WT5oMWkrYzyO1zOT@EwwTZpibGlGPITlKz9bNp8k4nWlgfFWaYxvocNNNEvspuykYvu7JWMfk@IlLHrNRGOHFOMOJ6Xr9vtRgxreuFmCaJiyvGqwxGhAZDTG8uiAmiCTpdLdKcTcp3GfoEeLKId6W0Q7t39uJOqkkZxxeWqSUk4uQU84bselTZJLgzaML@AmTjRcK6SswnkdjPkor5Q7gZNhJAhAaMVRLtmHkh3cpLMm@IijA7S9BqyFSpBE9LThWjhYp/@WYOyVX2/uaIuHxjhXOl4XSNcWEq0qONc8SOa@Ob0eNa4ZyhQpaIjPIIVt0ZRsOrt7q/5sWygfQZDSnKwtfYsBGuOrh4QN/XGTGtfQgZOqdMnUiEoPhAaLBhoLtEo57UayXIX21xkKx8O6QQ8jWkDIZw8/D3UJuPNeK1pqo8h1a4wsvia3jDZf5TakSMJQ8g7y66Eoqi4vXAlAJBhT@UqJIMCtKWOPQwF2veNyXgpR3UdUsFLCsKSP7BU1sfOckQ6i6gyPV50cxVk5nrkwcjOBkGIxO0@CCOkss7MkUGiim4mLk@PJ7PYkOUghNrwvFKeu0L2SpqHtOSEgh7gu@olEOSqpoKg5mBMfr/qpRMvfnPqs6KQWJ1OJPhbDo1xpMvVpMZWaqnZlJV00VZLo4bu1phKJFL6LsJUKf@4fX01xXZ5bm1BnkZHSMrR9NkKQ0yqT1m35X2P1nC9lGx3DwHNvhpvlV0NCrKScss93wK6W@cgAvtv/dGuNZarBRMcKYL905rKLJwtC1lizmOrRLKx0jac966DArGn7bfX@cGcn5fb1ZGwMjc6j4WqxWAQTn7jO741tNbaSOv1COnehfdHtFgZXfxm@Pymw7I8iDglQNivoiLqEBkWc7w9PJTIEcKCsyJ3TF1mx1r9ot90QDDihROdRt0lO7Q1B8QTUsUYv7w95A4hB6gn2FzQQ7ftF2dF3FYqiqaGYYygqDZPgy6w5PSPy4EMb9tn2pIqBQTAbayaat/zKxhfMIIhswp3F7ov9L4l5cvZV1O32A/UBoY/hKWDh22SBnR23QFGy4ISRb/dexOyPNlDRZafr3CtGFpfXAc5MTCbOhPELD9/4@9Fp7XrgZY9@ztK0Qk1@iGY@hH/qQGVPs752Fn8HsMKHhPadcp@HA6/JdJrMTFO9HsHJE2H0qBTMXPuksvi8J6ZpdntuEHU2unl21kBN91kXML7suXu5JTdkt8TNfroutUHDosDQOMHnyt1K4KrZP08sXo7a7btJRQ4DIB37XRJRIqH8OYHIZwA8AvXwI3rCi/ZPORrWOxMORUTBQbCOabmDAg0UyGTuNyu/XXnValUtDR4@VNXqJj3kcqq6WVXb@LC5qbbpfRPvP1RWVlfXReZu@1/o46b5@E1tEgze4XzYPBtu0yulVXBvDNba6OKlQmUpWF9qVJ5vrMeFo@omrvXT03/@23/9z3//b4WqfvkfeNnkl6OfbaZ8Pl9Yan5Z@uHbOt6Pto@Xl06OlgbHy6fr4LK/s9fwfn2UCxPz0fzwJLMos4Dzle1IzTqbvc/oosrE9DsPh59JupTVYjMuLOqvsUSOYhm72Iyc7xHuUZ7QEt4EHZhcyhMSiwR0jO146p1mBAM8mm@IkoQL7EClvJytmI17uIOxGeypyqL2xMM662WEOy2JJwXcxaUZK9fpxVEPO@CXrPNK8zKZkH47o4bm38LPb@LTzf61evDJUw@K6kGgHmSz/FNae0Zf/aVCB7dzJRstB7LZgFKSowWYGaq4w4oerx841s4EuTOZJQ7ZA0jGTQVnlltwgV398WUZCbgWn2YWENlTyRYJHzKhyOKXpd436pYvlONbNnXVhhWFhl7FcGXOiYrtX6hAYSyGAEnN50KQcp@qxEkf30jGU8F80X2d4WhCDBhk3X@5w@MeH2guWuppm@fUWgphjth8Xr5iblyXy9CMNlKk/gQBPlCR5WSRbxIuLy5nxMrbaSU3U25hu@3TzCe2DuNoZGzTpdDflMMEYs3tEm6pp@@1aENuOV5R2Y49XnGqyk7afquMU@T8ojvqDPR1Ba4dA@qLre2bjCT0KAMSOOKzvzw9wnijwHiKmugWCZY1Vq0@mi4joaevplMH@3k5OXKIUPjZo7H9dWJs@wW@JWLYQXiAkbKmfO2w042115UhE/s0HJ4gOmDY5oBqIzk34/08RGidwLjftkjnGTKbnCfjmZqyOBiGp@dhoBZ3@4fDcFynaYs0n1Ez71ML4YIJSGDw6apnNc8gLC3SXcIUsU1hyyEEL@iOdXg06dusvXOCLjVDQbtdwSBIsRNTMvqa6qsJOiZc/R2d4KI8JbztaaQWsSx5YWmkIWXdazM8zKaGTsbU4I4dO3CyGUHVjkzDC7rQBSbacz74JUnehY8AXXdW3wLUVxHWnqF@zE6nUS9MTU6DbsZc9C@sK5kXMZ45FKVYI2U0lCelJOIdsCI98ue0FwiZm4w7o8yC5y18inU4t0V3HmEn39YWvxCqjg1AxwHM@GaIetfriLCcmKGSGBh5VWfLf4LQ7oanhN/4KhyDFT8tej/eK/hHP3/qHT/wPvW@fvrdZ0y0SDazbE4t6sNsI7H0WKGZsRCkXo1VWmxcDX7qpTN86im5w@KQgBApeEc/F46/FgihT4sIdf9pUQiS6jJgUphfXwHgC1NoLqaxKCxmFvwHvul878eSr2hu5V/0oXzw5ZewMItK3qandc6wTaD4nu5vF3LlJC48XSk@Xik9ppXQaXSdG0YXmG9z8cVJdE2qRIzlLE09n35PcUOKEN@u43CdPl5TOyWsidw9ifUlJS1C9TDnejKWrahMXniC8hOV2V0qrrj4Nk@Iw0cs@ANFLGfysi8oMR10uM/D/Bn3z1FPGEOuTd4OEY6ElYHYiPAWag6QTfCVmzjUN8Nlme855dUWfLcyEOrewqIzW/T6vZxW1vz88jqUaNya6T4tPi1OjtGpIZoaoUtamVq@p0obPz75j/@@99viaHFjpfBhSL@jxd8W154uyiM90Nsj83a5uLH4HNnWvi2OC7QGpscn//E/qfzGXwgOUsbP6c/GqoG1Nl7cyFW4yNfFjTV6KK2sUL3/61//ldqwJCs2xGJdagSKEVs3FNkKe8y7lK7qaKUsS5cTscIXswBDLAxpbU4vMIy6Xnla5G26RW1VcRlpz1fGHkVP8WyYNWJTIdnJMPYUpBlJgQoqyAlIY0LRVo7thjHbAPMmaKpf7ufXYloB/KLNOWyV1nTjfgyToSVZFlEHelIjreflYaP4Y9aad5SzxqZk3aiQWNppWfv00Tqxw9t@NOo001YSZrieN8Or6CQPPsxHrQtaU/Xibv/XYeGSWPK8tPK00MbmfoHtuAsDhpQbjPO/kyKogwHRwpCNTgM1pB7on8OFV8DRgkih37FnUiaeJGnZg6gpe1jpmMSURe74BXI8jObkE1Xa47@kwCNypg4E6cRK@9Sjknv7ZZV9aDNKPl7z@sDmLRvHahcYObGGHbBsyme4DdgdNO3JV4enfAmJS8HrumTJh61WI9RpXmYha0KlBZmFs6g7qGTb4t4dvlNxYqLpL2rmjVByHewg5HIs6ADrPBqFtESvZPkL1uNJDXCTos9arau4hKxtnVev6lsVjroyp@orqfqKehRaQlKP5RnHG5tys4lsqWCrchg1cKQ2s2KqLTZBm4d5/gEGsXRLvY1rCbo5fAOSqJY0R1uVud0W8FqYeOQqkjt7srUokaszi8nlx8DkkBvU0J1Qb14qIwEBL7hlWCjT@4HcgKiYMKOdXkb8@U0kG/8eGgy3YQ@uRF23deJ8VKal3iVi33RGfJdSEQm0X1nXBjsjs4cFbV1s2RC0WWy8ZH2wVLvMiy3OaLqjzGGgjUuobFb2qY6ayoaXbevotRIogj5ki6WVR49X1548fYYoZwu6tbPBoFAeq4DBWUgwWKP2aJGN75VKdjkrnxCCerpKQJ8FFgdwMOu68n3j9vnKv1cpFTWwYpZhXXEYDSmutysZZAJxGOUxI9AaxRtmPe/H8hEadvyp5X@l/4m/jX9AZjjjjjYU0jv98DbxTJU5F4cDFRbM7BTHewQPKr5OcfNG/fY@vE1EsHUVtqeKXsMDxOhs2L84PXO5I69dWx3SgCGCs19qrKBeRqPEwZiDFXRRveFQd25fVAy8o@kWwCgXUwJ0PgFOw0z7rQy1pSlGxzJNQvCsiRurOEJ0TEdddmbu7PVVbXd7ErFFNwwdw827lq2k3LEnMziQQaxep7mHRF3t7YKvkmqZFKS8KrOAKyJfia/Dh7gr3UQgaocqRlaz3jDy5pGlxLyYuDZNilI/Aq8ZMEvF20lp7rWaVoAgRhDq3SQrxAJ7nuOSLMHJ7WSMU/BytuzYiL7pxDE7mNOVZX1tUcqZOKrAQuYGgNi3KWalIcUyepQfaxx4WXobwRzlVjS2BrQZsl2pRjNzcpgJtrqNxQE2oo4bWqD99d2tQG3X6M/Oh@0AivJm9Se024Z4vhnfksa3VFb1HdMFrrdYtrmFzdRvuKJEzFLUDmMTBCF82xIVMUq8BtTqO5r2MqiPUmP7OOEKsGuolXCzO6oHCRy98B7Igl68W1ccfF2Hv5Vl82pa0liXKnpYyBbX/IHt0GQhqdVCElLeAcTKJAjrqCXh9oWE4cUCnTXvUK9dDGPXd2bzdIplZUFFavtOgcie5tkbKTOPLVY0W6yU0Y/z@IL5di5vnETtvr6LZpnjFt6498d4I3d35sj9f8EctX8OdzzS3PGoDNkj3GHdhvONTg7D3p/BMSdjnoMbrc5pB/tDbecVjSgGDgAWeMAQd0gpsVRE224QJ8qbnfBwcj6CkdDKKi4G/KHGP9aNf1yGzOXH7ej/1cbn/sGNX9WNXy1jrpnR81q1c9yt/2NanKiEXvrDzO6FuivZ/D/a0jXd0rUyZtMZ3fx/vaW5/0MtfaJb@qQMjwly4CDu6@dzs2gi1YOtej0xt8hntNMuD3HsZ3Olj7VXq5KlxUO7exGfVaCtqz@M/1ON/1NII35CGDqcRVjbULuWl@WpXJYXzZJ3ORQuWUlLpL3GM7rTXj1hJesRPUGJkOaNraFeqJBCHkhictqUT/THRPrayeeuOIts18EycXDuLKBlRVjykyEumq8OkrmyZueVbfaBrLYO918//C9ChvPws76FRsija6@ibtfMJO4S7NB6ndKNcZoD2Ad6zZFiFU1ORnakb3tbdlm4WaqxY4uJeXH2IkGO2nD@R2upc@gbTlRubBkRbfK6vFlVwTTXLC/kC7VdMs1usm7xH@LSZ5pLn5XVvl4Y3ESqUG/4aV5M1mkrq6vz5gAplccPBmAxoPxzRtX/Bg)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/kwprl)

PyPy is separated with `-x is -x` as described [here](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#object-identity-of-primitive-values-is-and-id):

```py
x=9;print(-x is-x and+391or 1)
```

`+` is for Moorhens.

Answer (score 1):

## 392. Befunge-98 ([zigfunge98](https://github.com/adyxax/zigfunge98)), 16500 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [zfunge answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256627).

Answer (score 1):

## 393. Befunge-98 ([nimfunge98](https://github.com/adyxax/nimfunge98)), 16500 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [zfunge answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256627).

Answer (score 1):

## 395. Python 3 ([Cython](https://cython.org)), 16570 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S         \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse       22222222222222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 11 11 372364376371289369389284373370285329368367374377388375   366392393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::PrullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t"6F ._#^*2*giogrlopstdisp[]!!?48[]?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4oya:nlet d=/>;~ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$:     >2y2* 001- #vk!>9*+'P:3+'D'34#v (\$>+1y'+*+01-2/+10k !8*+55*%3*'R+:8g,:1+8g,:2+8g:' -!#@_,@   9s)
endif #               A=AgRA; >82y/;AC;#^_"873",,,@_>2+^     $/       >0   ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgwDcpUqVSqW7pdlWpWqW69/qSLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdPbu9btsz6@lpT7TbHt92z3q2vZ6I8U7srNs79kyEvR8nHPPJP6D82NhwbLj/Qe85JwEQlEipbnscMbELEkA@T2aezDx5Tj4OOro3/NnPYnixZ441H1jOhE0Mb8J6rnlquDK7P2f3dNPLa1lBwFC77mA6MuyJVxFiTGXM0u3BVB8YrG9aE8NNM88wWMewnDPw1xjbntpTz@jVwZZlzDbO2IHdNXsAgU2cE8M23xou@OUYe2BYF6OLCes6o5Fu9zw2dk17Qr55xp7pYOlPuydM73gTV@9OTMcGrwJjL2xLH3V6OqPgY9fgkYoMQHVPKM6yT4mxJ47rGZCC0zU8z0HHMjjqruk83n360ZXwaoZ9pEOmxpYxu5K8qrJPTcPtXY2hsU@OHz686pplX5Mcmz28niU1x3anE@dgchV@nu0ODFtnmlyWtaueBUDmxLBKmVLmqlcR6tOYmN2ldMDjoelC7ep@LbKubkNtYV1uMWM0nsyZxOtft6ywbj2me2zqTXWLwtnTUcdwg4DeRHcnpj1gZ@ZkyCZD0wvjUWhvrHcNqWdY5sicGD1mmRDJ6ftQALTdYyfG/Mxxocp9mI5tzSGi0TX7JkYJ8gEA8UpMhgaHM9LnUMn2BBoH05kH2bCMAFpSiEH4B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjkrWd6escCoJ056xl9fWpN0qwDfoBkcj8bGrbfmAGcDCCOHZ6r11PKmrFo83qvxzLQjiEfJwYzAWuUrQrLZsGdOS5gDUIFOfKBUbvmZTRmUGdQRX2nwvKZDPjvhy6YW93yHD8zy1lDTxv6KtUZwn3mOgNXHwE2egbh9JODZ8zrOi7Y4MawvD/dBKarT9j2NovvP30QZ/WwWmS3I4RVVGPnUAWxwJOd6tYUWki0JhyoHzeMLWCVxTfiFRYHtGgZlsuxHHTbEtPygCQ1UwYD9H8tq8JdYFqJ5VToQXmW1YrxNKbVd/WBaRkc0gAhFbHxQxANnpkcy6olHnLgWH0erEsJFlm2xApFVsyzIjzLrKxBigg@x9RyHu4C3ACtDNlR4c7mOKBF24e2iu1tj/X1kWnNfegEvsvyKisCRMizCpC1EkCAdzaLdxZuytbyFYU9GQLGh/opgJcs8wQpkhESJaxGBV7K1pZCVBHJLk/eG2LygD5AXL7EipB8ATCRgywAdrUSJJ/P8IJ4Q8Oy/GhDD6NRbosZuCHnRcBDCWogA7jMIDKLcIMdaJ4GxE0DSqYBcdKAoGgamLOYBIQrgF8BqrPg42uoeyeQEE9H6xHygaoDGBWxjYRMRSQBBKgtloU6K7AcNIYsNoZ8lkH@IS/FAgNaVlJZKcdKRQb4LGcY1I0K@cKWogINVSE/KgKD@lehAaiQJxWwrQJQNZtnQgTZahb9IW4W4gJq1BzEyYEZKk4t4A3xoGWokKQKaWpaedEQIW9aHsqbz1IL1QpQu0XwA7xpkFcNmpMGudVK4I9xS4DDEjZgaLYcETriAWoFmzy0Q0BGHvJDcCEsmLViluNPt8ZDvYMUm8fs9DFqAbtCAdEIUTNYPHjnEJuQlQyAwV4A2degBWSpx8A7FyZvqQCkgeCNnklE2jKBfqkhhoppapCv9fFkgTa1QDkazyfD0E3jbg4QTxMIoDHQu/PQE3pfOvRcuBay6KoRvV0AyuTQ1QPq6kw9awEkNOQ0Sso4Na2FW4nceobe65ve8N0irzlKpGPoE9s8WaSSz6cjSNUjHgX0WHIqZqNhJ6YEQ9ZgiKZFWbQihhk7YQUtZVlVKXsdoz@1B4ZULkXyRz6TqTuBwWWRZpk7u@ZgAOPyAo6apmLSYLlwzlMOrWx2IoSOiF1M0zVhCL/LukNgKkLPModfLi9gZDWEMdc7OLJLwInBSFDGsatvzljnbpdGjkUGs4Sn7tAcB4ErawNHKpcSmZUKkbZBmHtbyoSkGa@W/Nox7UScxZPCpQDjDecuo6M1DGqf4kiFYy82XRhbHeIcFuQzYQejYxKQtjzQw8hrARmFSunqOArjmGTQmBrAMScyg0SAFTScU2RdaWBcSsajwbPjIqcKnE7PcF2GYYG99dI0zHrTjme8mSIvtchXH8ZtA4b3vm5aYQZoHNEnxATAO@5BevPlbPddZ0SDzQiHUctxxmtYFhi0zxDQI@fMWGR9Mabr47EFnBO4G5xxg8yc6cRzE4MeTZVnCCJhPKhwAEhJAcdhukaXcO8XHWJngTdZzmKFafW7WYRyP8JSZaGzALvhYRx7alkV4HWMLsvWlZ5xqqALZ7uW2S3MQ8CIATvlg@jowC9jzikXIaS7mkws3nFQs54zWi4aH18PwqIPTWSOrDN9DrXXh6HVmOkj4OoZss7Qc9kIWgyvQawJkFuwWAes59jxSQjlzAVGFgodloSYZcTJxBwZIAE5EAVrPEeZxtGdctaZQ1MmbOVkEnl4Tq4gShauIoo75CIOvLMAy9ebdhFrmLZpUwsCNslDPt8FUsndhInLmk0dbhd4urEv5clowIDPMWsRIcHjvd3nvrsEEflUw/ZAtPBkZqIMBi1/4PShsZ2ZUHYgWBB1AbtLSEAUhE4zuSsLhHJsQKMTi5msOx4zcIdBCZrnw0wJ2FDntcnegqc1BDGiO3XdOZuNoSbMEYSadJ1@H1rvW2M8BBBs1GPdeRe6J1QytZ7xfCb0HCIy3fFyURe2TQPC2Cic7D37RTYwAPXAuPZRSsVmvyjEeEzFIHToNmdqbR2whcXojueEGiG2iNF3HBnde47hUYNx3JOw@2NinjGg7gF9rb8gSCNk0qGl2iRc9ID6@F0M4WOCwsrCYFJ@S/jIsKH7dKFlQseHKsR63WV9ELYjbCzKG3q3a4wnfltxiKSZdoTvP3yIfD@5Sj4w2RsKm/fY9pWWA0HD1hPhZ1EOwqyPfXFER3rrS/QSMR@h6MmpizW/ljyEOL2SuvgKwyzl4JW4Jg9j6hYoBBGhmE6QnCCFNLtDpIcTpDjEc0OPc6fXiw9u0eTdEZP6YdqYGxVIjyAroRPmYz0MCW7rOiB5bCGs@pIDBl1yuAW07o1WQHbCTFq9qKus6DIQxtuAjhzbWQEVkBnCxSDLPlQX1BifI@XQrbAxUnfxluoIifZikgkHMxhHx2PHhZ7BCc@cZhSoyiKtyxfEE@F4kZTZ/eXhFYaNOA76ExwJIcLY0qEtYBfDngrSlQ7UAggZF5SB7jk8xUiGqdcTLD9/Z0T@eWOC8dS2DRTQdHfOgUDxYIiGhObMdF0ghac4UPBxKBhQZGqnMC7ovR5SV0QH9furicvYovemHXN2VRrvoqP82hNOdZf1URB3gfGATpSI9714skruFDPiJSrOeKJQVP4UISAFkqHKE32Q7WGgeAiE5vnc7ibEpS4mppk4nfRLYhIMGJHzaexjEBeu5g5FCGw0oxPo12SrsgEM4ZIETwndKCfoocjoobvAa0AnBEmzXO51dHYB1MNl0myPiyOBWKLKuTAtw@6FafmIwLxEyyvzJDy3SwYpMrJhCTA4lZwGiSUEfiAmKKIIDorij6/oQBwf9yPehjtObZqPYwnOjiTZecgAwwCQoMyYwICYXXPS9lmWu3cD5mWjVoPGBhwVkM1eMirVBhOXMlBqCCwTR@InIk@c5xPsG4kklBcDX/LcAOsELbVWZ@eToQs9juyXAgQCtAo2tuQAsX49PzVPpr2rFW2jIwYSsdcB42R2J2JVAAaA94baTViNL2EVJN84YhUbL8Yn0NcaL7lihYp@MNfwkAWu@VmJ1HACc@C31ZUo4lF9t0WD3pt3LZ8l4Cbo7JwadSD7J/6EVkiI0j5PEHTaaz2VA8HuwOGwZ7vHj2p@X@SeSse0K0sOltPVLXLexOBiEPfxwf2j3aNfbK@AYZmdylUHxcyVCjjUTmfSwJ4qOVmrbEZhLAA/aN8MGyMuhxEF35tJzizCKs27MLjMAnQeHn3tKkqAE0J0UApgxvsKS8PDANMldHRveGUQZoNUCpIMowRhmXTAApihAbOO/nqQn2fTt2@x8q5mauy7Y86sqc4BBI7KgR3Ek9HzCgMWeHX6fESkuMCJmjYuOCxM0ZBBfj5CzvlqZoidjjSZjw4f7h/VCKw/tyZREMWbAC@luz0Z2rw1BTF8VRggf2DqspS8yDjy1JTXlQjudpcQvKhbtgY@AEB5R3aYZI2ConlDyPve1bKRq9QNWwDZCcJVvjLKD3W/bEYj@cAhroti76pRlDwWg1XotHLECn2Xh61uPm8Uc@XosNVdpNmLAqXFARgHAr7RBa8TT0IXecFF@my1n/3nj69l3CMmEkQBKciZZzGZ0vIsAaUXyWRxT9kDKc2xDPlTongiE5OKEg/WB@SuRwJoJPz@zJwkMkn@VpMQFlLf3T3QHgSB/Wlrms0goQHlcRyZ3D6u83U9aCO2YzkDh21BHM4dBgkC27S2mLsDx75WQzo6YlFjuFQI9Bcnb/QxjDXmWxIeKVZUZOWLjrrtnQGVVgtZRBJhiEApFF5@rZ/qgK5FuZ8ffL4Pg4iaz2RCc4YuQEEkDqELTd2IKzkwCRKS/fysLGC4bHittwceUmTdDgvtE7ow4u7Ce6UjUUxZWRl@ZZY@dq5h/LUzv9K0wIU3LTBEUHbw9Nnjg6f7T3Y/a060fH7JnsuUC4A4SK8DvJA85HjD3rrFuyYWC8HFoG@42L2ACkxBQAlWjaaeC4RbxiAyz8CaVsMXXBMfO0M77iWvFuYMfaXXdpc3oSfY@XhQPyII2j0LhRGXr1rjeI7tZziZjL2KokAvH047MgityuuuY@kDheLBwGBZioqiy8Ehzm14q2JAZry5wWPwCS5gHeY0i6hbIweEF1r7RtLAEhw8zVxZ5mAIsjAukBtuUg5bMJVG6YGEALKyEpaNCDDZALf@O6gnkTftr6paibdrNaPlFDEIttT9IexG3wDRKQGjFaAiecXKmnebd9kcqDRCugokxuQtmuTwGI4FFgNGkmZOUc4PkEPUAudMkVYQjt5McUYXqJSSz@SKaiGvgFgGYhrwrBLOu0kjfdIdShNHAniS06d5g0gr7Htd3e7LW74hyCzwfXegqNnGy2bTbgGD3rxLecP158a81VBbySq7HmXLD5@sQutdKh623cAB2i4ZoWnSm62hZz39Ojnr6dS7ekyZjMb@mCON2ZNdYKTeOkCve0a072EEJeqpbC2FVTDwO2XFhJCFUQV8IKYU6FAw0kLTUzBfEjC9yB5CywG6FYnAFrMZIcM0nwyBfmRZYo9MyescLjpnqVxkRNIsZTHZRb7mMwI95mEx0TgIO8jbBGHiPEG@sSRCuFDKx45mOnGPFmaQkcIpWm8MtUYz3F0cFjyclJzAcBx2NRwWoDXhqMDOjDhO3usenyKFSP7mgiA@CIchBFoKCKfB7XA7BbQ6ikXzAUCqoCHjXO1wMbWJswzQtCFByhPOdgDLYtOSxQAIG0TmBdnlBeEpkctykU5s58xGaB2DlaSOOeErDM7UxUV2sxctGwTPajwMQKPCRQYSWo3vGF0@tcsjUylA6tTZyBg5OHcB7BzRHoOKoPOVfBQ@PZwmh36ckXCZEuBL7N4ekM2uwSeopBFKbdCG91l84iq70ueKLr2F7nMDM4eFj1SxX@nHAQKW91XQtIw/5UrskDOiQJ/SBA963g/4a795YesS9ZozNuyrQiYXQRPJKu1/iMf5ytN5fGNjI16J1@NpMO2AaRtNO2hKgWmHTBKZMJyMJoqRJhP6NigGurXil40A8izZwjYwQ1blrTlO6I1KJdtK6w3Vf2v4TkJVAOYhtIQvgBNP1mpoTCbF@hkuFIHAECn7Hrad513XHPso@Bg4EG6PdjHR72KuUUVh@GaMjGouSKkG8rQJN95sZJqt5nmzl2pextMYO1nVayCQArWcJEbywHWmY@AUG7mKBMQ02chWWtVOLZ6JbyUSJcmChPRk8k4pmdI5rhNxA9pUotmMA0p97DS6Q5fgzdJaMhkiCvLRN0GssaxEXD4vQfqdZCuZikPcZDwN40AtHge80CqnR4XGKQjeiB6aM0AldEwYU6MLGUSRaUUMu@vnxng4d6MBwmk@YOtxyn6xSQb3EuGwESXLb3n8KAe5NLUQMNo8HHDTOFuIDNp4zocTgee0qSxtyQoG@lOpP3ImuvKJDFKaHBmf4xtxRZJg6CUfDomK/cT0sAvrtuFMvejU5soZV0wdXI@HUyCWwb64NLQqcywY3aHD4pv3ADoLF5mQzON6mcRX3QIAva4MNxJRZINwhQbYGdrJZAJdpD1gNA2kUiY46QkWA/KF8Rs5TK1KcVgGEzIHtuMaEqAEYgi0bYs2Awr1YDH8gKbari2E@L40huLAZRpAER9ajk645eQ6sgg1HkXi2wOMcmT0BAvoRx/Io8zrwjV6ypZAS8OOO4QRAkqDlFgLa2vkeyiON@7JkxlEFRI4wkc9uTgJXO4Z62maVujm@5XAD1sFIHsIlYRisA0ydeAlqeCZ9Ct5n89DBZMCTw8f7PPJGhrdcTzHibv2yOlNgZH1BbUjwx6k2T60J9N2RiagIYj/9sQ6cpwJn1YAy7qpIC6lm6OppdMk09V5oBvjdZ2OY9Hc001RF@GnrqdbOp/1Cnx3P3kCwsWL4@c1uRIJpOinoxvTxonP1clyfB5EFzppkTdYj/J4wxQ38yKOW8F2UyQzvkcBPab@ZlOoo8C9iO5Bl8JFG9@9hO4j3GgKzLk/bUHW0NEPWKaAuPkUd9r5judq5hLd1wp9YTiVwnFOdZHbc1Uj99NJv7/knCXnEwlJk7VwzpEz34S6JJRGs5TngXBH6lKYKKAChQk3pq4NV6RwfEuNHC5lPgl3PgwNK1jLPAKOBdfrYNC3kK8CKQllAr551ACWfozLMkS6cbGPdYHr9a7xrNDZxhIPLcQ2qAPB4KYgSyNsKsyfbK9SF7Idf5HU42TVcdN8Hme7zpfWUYhzufyo8GWAzTaA2K5Xg11@64JhSvF4GIygUt4gBhWTdhNcK2q4N8Sj2X2BolQFTwH5ZaZlpOasuN@6iCseoaHPxGZzdiejfQaCEG7T3LyrDIwqbaxag69q4BP3edjOnEnA8WEoPlPeHQKdYanZMiqhfqZ237F6El@WgwbDuECHFeTvjAi3j/q7hA3TDXaO0tZdHhXpa2TT6TW4V6q0fj1AZJtqCAi6zzm7OEmfXrAGDHmnsje2zEmLXcoTpz30t2fZVze0ch7UdfW5J/gba2ps9@ijTxqZFocgjHRcaivxWpwF@6KBcQZGCTewgwm3B03MCXECtP3BxPKqMmRqRqsykH2AwROosjAhv0SY9QvjYlGWvgGiccLAnHvzUZoZyUu5b@mTiWHzNsfXO9ejmy9M@cnUKPkdf5WjwjK0FAScqYl@kMUqe378YP/oSIaW6yXi@7hkVIHuqHeHwKCsK3SAyWjhK@xOL87uYJwkzhMI0NVA@mj78aFRV6HRg/wBqSPtGBhuAhyTuNrTBWdaYKOInEPzEYSbvLoTwlEILGEkoUwErLIy/y9sLmr5@axAi08RJgHdibsVwK2ZlKe2@Ub2YKAhvhWC@MIqjBe1zQRRsU016e/iG@FaNUhYxDRCCRoNJr0FKgeBRdZqVfmmAwiLApg7QOyKIlUFbZ@vqUHV18AZWBqC4EevvWMvGxmp3EptrgJFO9r8ne@8/BG4CGEZtGesTHYzQf39WkfmeeCLj5xyvyBx@sqxjwrb5AaRT3JT8GCXFhEd2tS1vDlreesXdDIkJTT3gwUJSELMP5fgt1nyJ8oPMg9GI4dEkp2HSNcQ5ezignDINjVGOASTynhlXAbSJxCmxw6U5rF/JiHKHVBv9XeuYJ9tCmIgZi0vDaMPZ@GV0yvcqXQqRuNx7tC0TxxaYApN7Yys5pEjDGOPTqzrMXHnKz2WgoZ54GG1dbnzRp0@PVYEoHUWfwWfHGgG3@eFgYnUlSN60WT@ipSXd60sJevviaWRFsxMenNLSKlcosD9TsdcFxSQgJvRgveKYECksD1rck5Wg0MOOBUD4xEQLi69LIp@dcMTW8K7v3nXf//nb/QA/9drZwgDBU51hoY2DN1YU1J/bWX5UdFCj9UVy2fkp5apE2LIdBvIru5CkXQrNKwGTav@kgTD/wjXMPwah7aJD@Aab2hmPOd8CTJ4r05k1SqeDSSzuy7slQ1gPClabwLBrkdI4EyQaVAkIl28EowZX/OJiNhIxm7PVLBLi1Fj5vU@nE6m/AmM662VaI7xvqlv@iEzeb2jGgrfLn9Dlbv6ybTnSOOTQcinFlaEXZSeFp0lYAf89ec2GlcXnxeQbz8P3uuCLYY25Yxet7UKz556Y6lDUniP26gjjG5IwbX4c10Q0z81GBrWY8206PGBLdGHDg3F336h4AZXKYI08wqaLb0zRx5k@OVbWbiVAShOrZtKZbJr1rLH4/XxUZKk@OXy6tgzucvxsWqOQOGbaCU@i0YF9rfV3lKrMFyZI92StF7EuJaYr9oJcS1ouIhKcfDEBx37uLGR44DUnVq6uzDd0MQX@QiWEdbNSPvDxjOz6wA7MGZqUVa1YOiIDBhEMoO9eIuEcA8zPSL7LcxVaAzOsEihaTUJcLoT3KO6pk19AEHje0NxB26kkcjOOkx1nTO817IPQxBN@XP1iPZ2Za4@gDhJVtfSYRxfOxwsTQ7i5OMtDfXM9Ax6rEbsycqMTrrWSvflLhBM@0Wn8W5r1p5pOR57Ts@bEDRwAQv8ubpBR3Fp6rZEk@FR8w00KNhUsahQ3Ro4VqE0UHR4rK31qdtHuu@/P5TChRRKVW@hUAH749iq/15L108U9@S2CqJTki5uqI0YbxhiV5Epf@1lfelAMMCFu9Ule5gpUUxZ4VN9axLGJZczfR68f46hYx1qg6FjPCd2Grg7jFAugWHichb750ktd3NqvQ8jStfAFm8rRKRyTywDBit6XqtSpmXULxlDzWQ@nET1rakxNVYKGoed1wae579ByPjwTGX8Ymz6M/W4OIDnYcJQb33J8INyjeM02m4kJrpldo3bWZllojYG7nuMovMzMDxDw/UYA3s6XqrVJenMProZZcNx0KWd3lLu0OfL0qHSLZzSEn/uGXTfKDFxCQ93pNXymUzGZ2AiKy5LlpskqWwY97XJn0sJk8si5UVYXGVzI8bVaRBaonse15IgbZ1gT4HLZcU2bWMyx@cHUtOO41hfpqaAqOIpZQekVYn29t5UY9fYHf/UCltMXXg44dHpr5u04KONL1sCflBovqnSo0tCH1SbEi56jnBBatl68/RNZIHptlTwRC3OCfHdvtZ6XtKfDVHlkly8sddxDtXpGJbOX7NC7iZ4ZTl7I7xlouEv1uLiLl/SXSzFx64QpfEckGX2QEoZGiODrDdw@XoPdXP4r7WBZg7e67xnhtFVZvtGd12AsQl0wcbn0hpyhFmaODbIVxPcWIhyioVbV33XdRQ4WPVbieSDkT4wuLKYmyjlYsICd9NwsW5hXD11UeE7aLoQbaEFZH2TgE51Ysy94L0S4JN5F@p1Orp9uu1K5@/iHOgH9PZ1e2avD7H20BnaQ2PIN6qHtnWdA9rjhCv3uSnrkOvBEPfOjcdLe@qj@LQcy/oQfCJp5ITScfor87SPJ27xqNiXgsuP9/uvWyfv9AmnHWhY22uGxhTGJc@ZOGNDItu6oBZO9PDnOhoaLFL/vDNIN8r5gJHg/fPCv1W2HOjOZDymV3tsTT16UFSJDkrfxjf1@dYU2oXpuAP5rTPqyL6j7O9boSXw1SSmY066Qzypzlu2MXA63aF5W6Z97RhKMOXDrR8kuyJmTCY9QGfZMgG97lzG9lKL@j/H18G6Svdnj/iwFhpu4FdWzdDRWXBprJ90PT4biiZWwQnhSG/kJ8YrdOa@8mZqThZAI3uZwuldviyBhnV593dPrOWs6FDGggz7uyrWtlJi0pEhl4wMMDzqumSX97lFulg2yx/rMhQtJeUosi/ly6Db3/tDs4NmZN4W3Jfa19KmpZWDnD2cDrzrBJNP1/eARcPH@mkL2jwdmbKGMUu3/dc6NGuWgqcq4d0Gnmtq3Limkr9xUYXCqZakOya82vCCqpuunUOzzLHHn0zqr12K8/cygSx@db2Q42a@Wpj2K6Zn9PkSCJpuYxFHjos7kYEHkbq4ko4z6EjMOePFCZftDICoSxZbBA7CrmNbVm4TWl394ZgpffbUGOi41/qxOcHNmitaBTXZVduLboX99anumV@fQsnWNTZUE8GXId2oLgG0rYD3RB@Y3UdLFRFm0kewv9OTv5aaPzpdr4uzoenhjqbQcMPEFDY53oix1bVBblgR8uq8faghY9GB@LnLlaFXza074zkeT5uT6aZpdXNCs6z@e53ouG4T2I2ZOJuOxlPPf63OA@2Zis5Cj07I3TszAbj0BkgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFbgwf1BcGNdx45@bljNgn5cyDJg2YMKQOV/RcO7D8PwMN@S49oqWSGl/4LInTnRILi/YG6hbA89X2Obk5tmcyQQ35wRvLAwfOfCEgvIYn/K9LwtBOl6Nkce38/qLs9C3jO/Q8p47U7droDFUcBIVC/xUjb1g9zGe6HBQQctZVErrOhZ0LzBYK7tM17GnE8md2jeOCoUbR4UKqriKNAOW@Pr@kxfJaGug3dq3caGBErSFae2GgSuNzLSBEVtPR5dDB7LEA66c6Yi2Ct8SZxc1SHWJXD9wVsk7z@YwgHywwATEfzp6YHRx2fDWtJ86TxzbgdFoDIRydGRwJQNLGz1WR8Roj/EYPeCnd2syzwnsmkGIcxv62OhA/VoL04eMRRzwA32irxmKaG6Q5L/QdGtbMa2O4b6mSb@IeZ1Iu5yhR8aMZIv1DYb3QWnS7XKWGOfjlvrI0oqNN3Ycmz@J2mbgpT65marAUECPD18ol3Ej/tK8wEr5bLmoh6d8l4jR41ow1pXVNTqOxZ837EmyTb4nQHdNw1Meo1IFcivkmATcl3cjDSneSEMWohFwsqe6R4v0q0WNBUh19iW2AA11t@vgSphvuGF3TkQTwi1kOtzbzzcOdADxM6BYenfqayi9LVvWqDOix1qBIVKbR0YHTwV1SH3IRJ9dr0w@M@TrTojs6Ao1DgTkCjt1gSWegTSSvH3YWpKjlrFqjulBlHrtcjlt1pFs0@i@1XHWzCF8Leaml/yhzMpTMq6Zq450I5pFVnQ6Wr@yJy1vXQOGxjKkydAFmV@Z3DS9Heh1WbEeMh0ZuMi8vAqzlnV1vCEV1lm9nh4SV9eQfAWDQEtCZYOcP5R213KeCB7@h/c/VmAQbhdyga4TIF23r@BD5qeu7b8@pAU@c7xJ35wdQr7xFMA6coLFykMUePGegaatdYWA2rOnFp99GET2XY16JI5JpP5Zkiwi1xNDMuxTiTTPza6XyOGHvpRdVBk8MXqSr3gBVxqkx8H5rzCY/16xgBqljbjZU1U4YmeFnL/9cxVyzwLKAPyWM5HGHr2Vsffs4PHhsTz21JXj0@4QT0dc4@OWNDlopUxkSuq17kbWO/l2tJ7pTZT7z1Vp7/GBjAHW4JuvaEjwwpW5pdfaec9Adayir5WC0NeYrGYQHx0/eZxaHNFkib2h64yMZNR77/nzNJ40@fj5Su9o7IfQO/rObG30g31VTa5ovi9sWh1cRz1XpLQO0rEB0ig0xkdcEcytzFXXGRu94/nY@AQGT6Tg3gcmX1hbyKf6qTnAXsjKaxFFHZWV5UIuGdmZDcK24YbvdfV5Yo6RWnbppfDX2u0oyDlkFTe7mnu4acX/KhfDMv5OhC8XSc1cb61R5cWK7v19M6aq6jo8P9f7UK8sv7aylgOsWh@2nNMPWEo2fOFFCp2kCbQqybx1H3lRGgHpVvCB0/O@Ixg7a7fB3AQgdC6s7PBnhj3XbYnWsm5iLyoQGze13Rjkc@MDFqTCHT6nqCF95RpfuKWeJbpkTN6S8LEbibK3d//gtghHPi5vDvXR0xfsme6h1pObA0ZzbHxAjhec0WsJ561Q5d7a5dSeC6C0G@ENxqv7c4U9192eY89nty/C0RlUHNq5TtoAFtookGGZM3PVWNXl81rPVm8zui1tfojDmS/xwVFtOD6g99/@Z6qayZCuI3yrGW69pWaCDs4SaNLnqEAv6nV8EJKGLvItMjgkV0qjj40Zbkfhs8GrhPqV41vhhrGvmFw/nNzkV7rBL3dDetf80JFl5Yx6A8D8DX4sL4fejx3rbOjIe7preCv2H6/M0E0FKd9QkHKEOvsq2mlh0TevZ/Hx6IL/Wtlaj42JmxsPnY6ZW1mG3T5qtWRPUEP7dX9/O4Xu0vaWgeMf@eD21emdTY2VCT3R3672IEpzstILiKAxnNKRiOveywukHeB5DXtgcoWO7L4z2SfbDYJZeOJ59V4Ec/xgOl6fY6CN@B2Mq@R8KeCnIDM7Zx67j0fjFmz6Ctkf98etdl/H07JwYhD1mj463g1a1@FzRYukuMjFZ8@WnPHw6OTwecTNNWazdUKvNFsnQ670WaT69Di3lOx2/eXpCmStP28E7AbQ4/C9lg/ixO7j59dJAopvw8nICnw@1u3FjOlShfWcCZ00XOn5bD6jbZQra3rId7Gt8nO7K5yXBHsYkE0T0vaUdhvV@bfb61rlsfEZrT0AG8QmnC3hQH3FS8YsNwxySFHWdlTnZMH8LGX3@Xho2rOVXqN1cWgXaeK1t7ob7LLnlnPGHodahdaRB201cP3UsNcRp1WHFaVy9mYuLHuFpVpXL/yTKf5rXZXcX8eoXaEZuCHiJmqC8Y@6ysPA8omWvDX8x8@D4LeH3bMcnL/vmdPR7YEJbCp1e0D3BvJ3FaB5ezD8wsjJ0HHt24MGzalSuW98YCY2PjjkaN51PiAPnX7/9kD7nnN7oCdTa2KizLI66FNnaqEGgVV@@@5gpXt9u95syhV5nSeqb/eGbnK9P@6LdKYeyEBmSDzDiNJrc7LkGLSZqBtqkzds2XaSV@B@7LCvod74Fah4@4F19PHDdeGWF2ymuMRPJ4IXxnWbesfz7K2d/K05IMuHdDrbHN0YdqHg78B1bG5LrhseF8r@0I0fnQfKG/3Og5f2FWdxVRP8gL8nBx/jSCRsqKDk8tfPotoKUBt6YhO1AW@SZgIIe3HBNnxtAOAhBvoFfP0HqDTUtKcGKjDg30Sa1DYhmVpNzZfZDn5urMLUDKWJX1Esc92MQWINtnnun@2vVNRLtlFjYkVkvnaFUNU6VxcOgFHRMRSKSScq25yAz2agGYDR12/YBaMJTamL@mTBJitRHSlVX3cC5Gnz/NnBs/3nx7vHL543Mq1LX7dCUArbhtQCDS53sj0RCu/jDQQl/vEA0ulhQXL0ZR6cCPWCcjH82tdy0WpLRVsUStzBOJvntq0opF5CkS4hf5LIUyNfHO7BicMOSkwV5GsWqXBND6SwAuqIgxYpTai0CsusSnisA9O/afv@Vz@OR774AcUKfkIRE/b1vUPrHDhOz0/RM9jtV5Diw92Dxy@O9lmQwUWrOTN7k2GtnOefA@Aqb6Ce@ibtt62xuB8lDnVVq8UfxgExcTnOKqQQhFTxQ0OHYAF2UJWIH3uLJTYJPmAwHlaK8p@/oVzGZTw6koSw8SBTcUgW2jw1lI2NDXYMjYQ9ODr4ZP@IYf73H5AzoghBsGPURvBnP@7xj9kE2sKCj0e6I@LQSduSENVIEqjpWGgSQZxT3x2v/4QkfTyG9HWEX60JP70lCPRhI2i3Z6RZ9IoSyCTpZeOfvPR1dAYJURMKPoCBq5Sob9P12KnpmagtBPPQR/WXy40dNzaSjlmZ7eL3MfErnDp9XQmyPrUnXMWcr2gqBi1NDmlOmm1SZvm3mMRIwPj2BjT2jgHCG/NsE4aPSYW9hpaIK4EVrk1Gkurxa1EC0BUyScjwRwJe05fpKU1Xef9r/0QZVBmYJ2D@jm@eZe6D7Vd8Wx/Mv8rNLxVsaNf1ay7yEs0QKuH1S8AzEuIfcR/5LKjNNfgsEIdqQAPCyswRVNMpYR2D8xT4UwJ6vICTaHwClQbNDWrM19zD0zPcVgK1AFcUBZsUTijINAoaM76J@Yo24EK@kFMVyKR0GgCkz3cMUDsDB5hMVqCbCKfmuPYKhNTt7W0m4qyiUStUec0qm/bLrPgqzOgmhBXOhpi5BoM4EGURA/zqfjQYfVJqEqMi9YqrcSRcPQeGJfLH4Qvtto8IkSUAWRxHBn4PYoZfkJ0Ar@1rte7gN1cjn3ba9AFJKoxJZEqKgq/z5qkzgeYDnXTxATeu8wY38fMhELW3evy7yqRMGtujfL1nLVQ1BN@Q8vuajDSAg8pmro6m0boVP0UQzxFERVzVfBsvWXPStFsKb5sMmukPVzRmG8y/rAzWtFle7t3rmn0TV/XyIrLYvee2g9OnD6EwLKEpWlZRC8lFkXK5lUXyS@QnA8VB9WEXkByQKSAZXcN87Yy93b39g48Pnz2/pr2WQsavBgO6X99ONSU53WiFhni0WMtVcv@h8vzJ/YdBRSwyXYhQYyD8fknUm0qyWBVBkItTdleLtiqHV0u3Psefcj0cV/Ob1W7KGkW6lg818yXSpZMu0kM6r3o1ca20Clv5/E1ZWsBTIqD3uLKBa1lNJM8vGy2QXexY/HpLWNERXsbkLewEYGp6W5sKNvbrhcOChV88P8bvSHrRvphd3RfFzSwqR0RdJxPnZKE@0neIeETKGyQDJFKQlSDo2t53yJn0hZJTjX@RnWtVjOqMi2S4kLkJ4xFQx8HH3ZGKLFQ0@9qJhyBXWGZHCHT1cS3FgTLVUEEx17OXSAr@l4V4wgn/c@@zykymba2JJFI7gpVmNyk8DuAlBejQyN09m4J888wZ8y9N0PalB0ZgOnKA/D6Y8ulOg308HUG4Pr2ODFpKBsotQWTAZDzMKuelgEr4@o5nKdQoDek1UOuxX3B51MsnZkl5aMx65gBoeyKZBop2R1VbLNSJjIUmHch2XKQ6W9TCjV3xI1QhEUX7l1KMPVtkQG/osmn3jFkifhZPVlqQPrrHzz49jSfFVW2JFHT7Gqt7VzV1h9kvqjdTEn3i985ADfYqalEuX6cS4HYVMNcYGXzmrlyWh55Any6tIef@fOI@BiOwEYn@SB@zxNTm2jZlRtZEM2GnSQ2hVOeafG2WSpFABS/ykBnF7JOJj98J3Z6zhFLDr9uCq2f38PXWHLOGKsstMFMiSbaJn5/cA44L9c8mBRCCIUqFwNawCYGYATninUTmDRzioD@EhRfpLF3hTV/joxU3B3FCpWb1uyzySdFlzlEslyt@hS5TxTKD1nedHMoKgL1G5wK@HrDrK@ICnIH4KwuxBSG/TvFilG6MZ@SRr8ELshOLaN8OFHsxgLXQjd0dungn9m3oK8AfVCovjh@2S0lFZKEmsIFr9nBFmH@xIhTx/G@MQTdVloLGq1yi@wijoc7VNlc1hqo/H1KHEa@Q1FgUDb7e6kBY9hZtU1VvbPV@RL8WIGQOBwD/xHQ7AId6coOp4hV@q4n9z34WQ2YjsamqJ233NBXPZ6rwUKt5lmd3NpuStNnI1O5t6iBFTd7MmiCTK1u5B6fGsN87GChNUWRZllOUrfPz8/jDrWfmyzwrSD1TK7yZzS@zheyb2WVWLb05GauFhvxm1hJLtfRJiz179tm79rukODudvxGbCS22d3ghqjkU@WOVMjvfKWRjJ2UQPyFdxk7YW7hO@gz/ZH7bi5h1NHf6IMLGRRZrNgHjqlgUFaURb8GfxP1XcHHBv1GX6/JO6927ZEPXJ7M5M01z7PV6cDtD4CC15HMG8vJdoPQ8gsKa9CYJCq/RrH99PiHP2GzXGAym@3pdw8P08r12dW5OH06efP5pcL3A6@1RJNpb/5vXqVRCkhor5ikqbT0fw69n/9lPNi7T58/a23/2zZFibODrEF/fuXyC5udq/s7Gxp3793O5tKZp3Pzs82e/uLu7m3uQzj9r5HdyUmZj@0//ZGND07Y1ZaPleWor3jg5@UzUMjlR/rMfxdvPnn3d8@rZ//Mb7@oqPorwOGVFoBNwZZkKRnyW4FaRx/rQK/Y2Bq1cjc3p144F7ucbTK3vFP/L9w7fxCaxuqZ86sJ7EnsTK5Ri3AgGsGUD22msHtvGYIXL2Fyp1WpgLP6Xfwvx6x8DHPSZb8Ojng9gFeaxulSjKBexegEMqqZBuv/3N74RySEnEzVi44LrHmvAJeaKmrjTgmuLrm0BNaxKGUUJwtmT4cRwmFq6q95FiwkWeNkGfqrCmDRjainH2OE9xo4aqVSqJbcluOSXNEmkqKrWVNW7QA6kO1u1mrTFuA7ZbDZ/F/XgJ2lKa@DAiGnc/fQf4oqtcqz@3OCOhFhh496rB/U6lClbz27VU3T5HYn6VLEkOs49kaXZqziIII3Wq8eMK76ui5mSJqbT6Xttss8QV9IsbEl48WcsFrpgl2VX3ZaiQBDfNfblw8X28frz/@3Pv//n36Pf9@n@D6iC1u6ZfWULAp1Cl6jDda9S6dbrYt0Vz5tor0M7ylRKlZLSvmwmtoACtY6YmvnoIp7Pxp@HqTeTFBsuSrbuJ4/2emzhXOcu9aib78EDkwPzS0GGJayROcTatXAwtPqb9aXGab0lIUNUkxpqId@SeKx6cJVZ4x5Uk6gVy2KrruW1Q3avPeMXG256zImBZFgI8Ojnt74oWz30WdjqUadYPYhWX4T5suHC/AqxRkNpGTQgBG7s3kZlo1QpVDSlXV9/QdOMWimoYRjPvNhpLLw4ZmMLhMbCpnnVLaiK0MKCFsy@TDiorHCyW1t7MaqlbEEVq75JazOxCo1Ey0raoC1mVDHsbTi/D9cG/OgPV2jF5wa5@M4U5Pq1wSrqlpZV8ncK@xqOr7dc0YFCgHGCdTudzttuB7gOXe/oXV2d6FN9ps/1SWfamXUm3WkXmCYeAdoa/7tZJ@@UnMAqS7FsXt2M3aVVHhX/2aKWLeSyxUK2qGqlcrZQzpbKWglcstliRivlsxo4lrKFYrYIjsVsqZQt4hiXLRSyZS1bzgqxd40NdsTJWYulgquZuvV6Ictt30gGB29JcmYxIfYPcNVVTWVbMNBl4AHcHRlB@MafqgosBhzbeevdVuPdFvT0emqbqGyrLvm5hJfcvtdKSZeXDTBXq/5/ux4aq3RxExSudZlKbb@sAxvzst5IAciXPkhZYgRUbtdb2@QTJuan5ntvt4ARklLbje2as0e3TD1NiueceMG51wLA20uZvXcvJYPpHgCob0LHTqZSm5K0gYNswx90IHCrngpKhXlIANtxfv5z3iAxAjm43L6sXza2Ly@3t@G/Tc9L/w2ul9vX/vRaXGvCLPxbSKOaDaXeVJo@1WmBXVbq6CIrTTDU4Q3hGlmt1GqgAS659d/mX04vnqELZrklQ66F2BbbiqFm1WxsS4i9ev/F/4J38/0Xv4@MJ4OfURFi50gflC0UW8tceoUHs5/Y7Am/bDDjHVjRBR2e1NHR5g8bV7YU5ZXMKnzxIKGWCkkZR/K202@jshaZvYKgSxwskk4maqWC2E6pc43FtsVCkejmL1y74vH4P3qllYtxPuOD2kZeeZ73JJLLRT4hcFXLqJJ6Uecf1ODfPvqFVdc/@oV1lxC7KDOjAvhJMI4YIQbtKKYokgQjX317hMdRcM1FQvH2tPaZ9GJXwvkYfUIral0@11A72K@Vy3W@XLT5jHrN1oMteKrw39@AYrBmH8I2@7XuCDjpZj@b15r49YWY1HmDv8dv8ceOu/g7eoM/dvwWf0cT/LEnHfwdv8Hfbgd/xyP83X@Dvydv8fdigL/mV7JZtSpunhNmUmpZvdyciYShKgxU9eZXJu68Qp8SE7UdDeRHf8oqkc2Vk7HmV4xZ1xhPKv7cIh4OMrqTql4rVzs1zQ/q72xGH9n0gi@z@1OJFY0lcdIzW847roTb8OABDqlsWXXc@E@/@81vxmu1uBSnr0DlwE3qYKAOBQIrxMzxnOC3dCF/UN@eF6/ei3@lQdMJ@XKrgZ4t8BBiNbapbqoZK9PNqB21AwaTZVyWGWaGak8lsStjsMw8M2eZkaP2wGTALwMmM9NnmQHL2BkbgoEvmCbtzARNfXgN4NcHQC78TNzh3VEzXQYJWSia0edt1TbGzFy0m0KDxZn4ygC5WVbljFwwW/iNrob46lVT2Wpp5RKTsV3L7carZrwlNkX8boNWzrHO3NhovhKBzciIvP2jC4t5Hgjj1ZjSbCoc8YAuqsnLy3Z7/@mDdlvBkbD5xDlc/A8PR1Hrjf/RofPk0Bk58D88PITea9RT91IwRty7V4Mxw3/txOrVnWaFRp5g9Ikp2zvNelZCcyEFA4qGbqkveS0gwru@0RTiZyAMnYEcVU2ANHVWPa1Wz8jwKbeCoY1mdAz/Z77BfxOEaiiLncF1SmDJhsazT5uhiRuUT8/A6VMGMmT4B2E1av2v8Df/2/o/ecGSLNFoJRPnl9sJupL4SybPL88v/Wc9mUj4lsQ2/NAB7Bjl/LKORgp0DqZGItlKXl5yN3gmktscYB2S2a5T3EU4GJliYZKULH8k/uu@IWn/asarwMPzeYJ8hvpRTKwyfbFHqNmcZTJJoHP@J2lwxVu/oI0YySp9j3Sz01Bbf/oj@uzQTpIC5XPVqrrFuEXLadVqLrAVS9VqKbBsJhLl61c9s6MWQJbK5ZLJahUsOwHYDFghboO9S7Eaa8KzdfcuT6SkXVwEMLO5QiqDe7Oq1SClPCRreHrXJ/rnB4f0xR4gNfkYfiqLk5JEhr73hQNBXKyId@8megYeI@jt7Cbv3tXKmYuL0GU8Bid1yand7pluu43u2YsLsS3Snp5yHuyZ0sWFmimn1HjScRNP8WOkkFRCUtkdrU6ploHIa7kiePsZyG9vF3L1eiEHLoVSPIn7AziJh/zGxXhVjJ1TGdRSkVNAsYrO0b1O0Jc9HGvPL2NUoSyXTyaAkCaBDb2M4c9FmsvHunw@CZi5FHlItVzmQZMsV0iUUmX/V9tIsjrwWfyHzGI2ldsqbt0Dtht/3mzVhTS5em7U1MvauVHBFYLLatf/jjxqvTHu3s2WAUWlTLUptNsPdo932@0ajGXIq8EDHYm6C6gMyI1XqveoXtVSnkEFckcpDkMCKwGWFW0rr5YQK4LZRy1WgAOBi3obbEPQ6I0PocxRtQGOIEJBaj24WI912AAvNkDJk5nMootZjPvTs9sNAzn88n1DK8Ul4TRwMcJL8LtdlrdJGLWfPd7d2z9Oa9sSi2kPd/fS2vMX92MqWvMLO3ln0X60v/vg8AVEePZ4f/f5/kcHn@y/eAbuHjtbXAGV95@Ld9S0wn7GPhVeu291w9CNqWG0z6bTszfstWm2Tag9awqFcgYu84w2lGWsL8pVhbtrevrr17o7pou9/@G33//wv3v/O999/zvffv873//pF9//Ntw/hvu7/P3df1PO4/OnX/yz333/278Djv8B7j@C@yc//eI3vsFvsv8x3P8p4vbH/h0Jx28BYP3KT7/43o9@@sWv/gDuf@nfP7h@/9pPVt/f/9b6G@N973dvDvPdfwv373FYQdjv/jZ3w/e18L/Nw/3qD97/i3/H/3/q/9D4O@//xR/jw7f80x/86X96/81/r2mlP/3X77/1vfff@ub7b33n/bf@sfb@N/61mok@fvf99//gr/7w9/7qD/9H@v@Ynr/3If/3P/inf/G//sX//hd/6N8/gfvfgeknf/Hvoav87R/8EP/f@4O//aMf4v9//ld/@we//re/8j@R4Te54f/5l/@GP//61/7j3/zWd/7qJ9/4m1//yd/85h/81f/xq//Xb/zHv/7vf/@v/8k30fE3f/JXf/Qrf/nNb//lt/75X37zizXPb9/4/OID3L/4B3D58Hx@CJwPKdeXdfni58rP3wcbi1SgnUDr/uX3v/FL0MD/BWPvv/1jPCAK95r/jzWVwvyY2/4/YNCulxl9MmCC@9fff/u7iKL/AVAE/xBf3wktSz7c8p2FBdD6Wysi/fJPv/jnPyJbzKjUackJB@uSVkptgUCzVS77A7a/GgVRfmkZWgjAT@k7SKGW/L6DtO39D7/x/kf/@P0Pf/P9D38FR2spV07vpiX1lqU8CJj/gHAYsPAh4TDgZ5B@O0XTelLqM7BtfJYvZW3brn722WdC@0LBk8j3Lthn8GOfBRfjXnhS2fcK/NAdjy4zcG@8etXC9d@Im6Jy4IrG374Xbs@HlCTtTmpHUTXuZVwomzwWq4JDtpRtRrKu9PtbFfgxeFQqW@dpaacJTB9FvRSMoEiqD3VDYaqezm5ldQio5Hg4VrHvZXKp4paugwicQrgp4nm2Ah4sn2WzlJ/kjM38ie8ZBpptkXFGM@F8OhyeAj7oX2SsxLKM2fxfFViKJsj5Mk1qYSSDH89PghuFPCSTmoUrcMQUMs6VbXEXWlyndHNlhiWYzVIzkLbBACmkwOs@8P21Wgoj1ngWwcoLUy8xykoqVYNyY2weJ90uIYjZfYICMWupI9beqs14xBTCqwfoSAnodCSqmpgq1R5AgrXZA4awEDiBffWqVi/VZnUE945jJzVL3ac8IbBaalZ/B/YawYR4QuzBO8hKqZZK1UuYIBaSV0@6zSspT4WjsqdYyq8DeOMZiZ17jN0R1ZLIV1Y2EGE8ND5Ti9AYEIKDfzO15ReH/oGR7i1C@AYl5afCuP8O8cQ7nE3GAABXkmRZZnDjpoUddg@8ZxxUipKFV4pDSFGLoBYQOjCciEoJKarfFFkg/Vht60tfCAwLs7m5KcTqYlY8lAl1isLckwodGME9lCjHVJhYKIvobNDpmSAvEL9K6W/GcTUyzjhgdifF73v3ttgdKCa9F24Ck1JZJ@fEOJTtVErUAH7dSQkvQf4RoJ0SoAtBntVo9TMlpNOMybUY@rHDw0M/E@TwsiakoJlrWRXtuAY3nU5jEEOW03I67b9lepOD7Btk8vXf8iYi98w1JwbTtFwVxLQqQycWlalUkLXR8d27d1ArtCmtcgBSLvP3p2m5EnmCA1cEZVnz4JiVlisLfAqAqYUcYwmaToYryfA8UQIaUlLghxl4NoIrEddKpTiFBPzLia1gw2JBRQrAD27RuWCWLy5ZITdRK04L8snnWB1LFlxcWC3lk4Hn3iHbO3zyZP/p8bjVYgJ@FXY6Mdpj1@kanpdAv92nD/i5F61cSMYaDcTKcUVDiiTsVzLYUFMHD44OnlcYx5JfZwkqR5VWr328lFUhNh5/uh3z93eJ@GlPR3yOz8oCFQmtDNQyGasLsa6BIhBuS0DRvMqqwhNvcN@ZsUQmLYpptYAiaBIXYSEfv@hMGSqe5lqqoBPiaRh5e5swINTPJVrXQSNUb0Go1/2dkUwV6s/3jyHC8SFTtYws1D9jMxkTlC6FulWzDHswGW7iFkOxmREjZdpsZNL407JZeKq5QlrNF1sbG9a5hGk2qZbPca/oJVjPJSzGV@FiwlcF9lVwggvSwA2gzJ8hPzis@lsgUcVjgu@DFNU89MukgLP8HJwwjl5V6A7Lq2RCbOPzzyesXgfJXzp4KMSAvAxZsAtQMnvyUKZq7k1dg3wHjPXMT0z8ZqvcM72xpc@hrwE2YpeXl32AdPCQaXWNrDxGD5@XXXLpgPlypgsxu1KpvVNzReFot1J5l9U0ARyELQW3GW5AA6DdGlsK/1U9SCSbLSlA2lRRhFc2mxWo@QoVQ2C0I@ddplaTeBvM5lTakCPgZ4D0WW2xxO6Hnd1ZhM1meFj0AQ82mLgsE/gVuZ9vKwhkA6ThHkT66HzV782Zu3ezOL2SzWXCeRQqMbuEutnM5rKIcTzj1Yrliv4KkiiKrZhgGRPWq4E51oQHnyrU1JjI0IZUJlvKCLFGrCH8//3yF8m2x/VsRt1WxmDUwZjbVnQwdsCY31Y6YDTBWN5WTDBO61k1s61M6wITtrl2aIbKp2rixJihMnruJtY9w@rLePSrJlICmrjtf22hHkSs92o9pzvFXTfVnmzatuGiqggeIZcTq46NektrwdIUEKnkuTConZFCC8GoDWRUheXauiX05I7Tm8veZG7hISrLcWtxYGzjgccCugEcD07n7WSzuUqDteSxM94RtHwx1VAzMFThrZbSWnrD2CkWKz25axm6u5Ov5EvpHp7P8lcOd/KZykD@7MnjR5PJ@MigQ1s7uTJEQOWRqOZtp1TJ51uNhiimGpRMq5FpyZyuSRsbQAwMvSfBG9cVPUkrtSByz3RrtXh8J6tqklrJZkqXwgJxiHMsYV3AqCksWRrxfu6Tjort2EClKmk9bZ4TFir9fv9y6zy1sAj6ucRtgJ9LSU93zkNrVYqEq7BpWjIXnuCi9wHd5/6SaUXU8iWx2qgu7MWCWG1dCvdGRs/U8axWM3N@PVYBqDmHGoOEmky4rLiOM6l0jL7jGouAWbUQBOQZuh4gJ16GyTUzmOL59eQKkUCz8@tQcnnxMowVZEu4vAS8c2QD2n3V33Xa09xQy7nWPtAuaD7bgVZwDBZ7@VKIbR19kq3XoarPc0Utl8/ltWyhkC9qMFCVcwUQ7zJqppDJaxpAyZVL5eIltGtFeRejj36yvfOgvVfosycJvcL19jZaLPnuqWmdl7ISz0ciWb28jL0TYneOPtFgZF17JWC0/kST6rVsvgymLJq0LGSYCZomaVkpq0pqFv@3GDT8f3h4Df4aPiFWVhOOUZnXUxhvgUew2WNUCjRx2LGDn4UbsPtGd02IvaFOG873XMfz/h5h7uv2Cfd6YHIN2qHXIx2/jemNzMlwTYgX4xHqATPcfzAI@6MOZBDJIQ9wHx6u5TirAhTZi2drSvkk/GYFIIN/tAKCHx189Og48j7e3917JBTY/cOnD6688n6gPHu8//A4tBa5bxA1H4L4xf3Hj69a/Vfu8MVRf@q4eAsPD1/kFo/QCc8zCzm4lgOFzgTEf6CVOFJgRUDkyxcDgyrgKZi7IIbf9Y35wsKYQeOn/LC26YWnMvi5/YpwHJzg1hlS2o7BulzdG84LkCpWX2ZQi2VBGDPbOWPFDOs5lqW7zOn3N8BxqONpVAM5YcvClohJnzmu1Tsze8aG8AQPvpZBoOhTJoRHAGQ07ZImEeCCULE3jGo2w5W2jjU12HTM1jrCC53Q6JqDIYzBZ04QQOjoOoP7y14Q34hek5sdJjwNcrvmY10PLoD0WMqL4p4oPtInetU1ii8zlcozF8Zi3RsY@zNoruwFdB/dnadL6aw4EQsPmdyOvdzStga4dmM5YxRevHEDuP2dXKnR2mn@9W/9@O/@5NcHNaA0zcxeJo8zT9s7Tx7nnLlesTkzqNSr71i@AtQOOGJGTK/PGMskImnlUr5UzmqldKlcyuXVQj6fVrU0iKPFMggYGbWkFkr5spou5crAmOTK4JsvF322Wgn4aGWrAmDtrjXtGdskZclDEKf4Yit7m9CTLKaH9ikTDYgjCigBT@iw/5ZZgzGVqRmWLTKAqLMuiz18uJd5@FAU76MFN6vsZUSxh5Z8KZMp3hdFg3z2SshkiQ6PU0INquKEWzKZ@4D1KQeAHx8RxSFa9gs4hyiKJlr2dh8@xHT6aNEwPgQ74T7cYgWWIgSz0QLcPgF4E0KDYLs8nRxldB8tmCT6POQ@e@Anih8F2UGfIx6MA3gUlHR3VxQPuGV3F332qNh5ntGvoWWXLlF0wQK9QRQHYBi40A9FsQNG7BOi2AVTd66D2whM@H0Ke6KL4pyjBxEkijMKrXdPRLEduGMyn/i5ySN2K2RReanvkaWMP1HUgkxjsGxoyYpiLrTkoGyPHn2iDyc9Y8CvucvfXSjpo0dZ3ZxN9x92PvqoMxh03Pnu/kdH6LW39wgYlPnU7Qw6fsROGy4HYu090vST0fzqBaU@aLcrurXS62vtdk63r3i1520Dcwix3kDO/GuACY3ae@C196h9T1@1WE4A20gORvDu4HV/BO/7eod7BRd50XvW6YhVbP6K0kwIKELgqjd2xxMgr3Z6pHddp4r2WY1l0sjFzBuFTKtKHmwEokCmeon@/QQ@dZx4Sp7PG7NaplWb1Yr@Nrd@QmzOtLwppjdGO2o5X9nQd1Qtl5pVUN@I04@zuKTusIR6d@stSzxN7mggFojNnR1JbKitHU0tVQrFl1tTUUxW8LmTLVbeJjLxDGP4SDaKrZ1iPhKjWEzpilYpFoE5A5xMYIzv4PROO5E4M/STZBJzS5MNUAQqK5tTOc1qPzFLz2o8X2yerM5qapXrZWeZa8B6@BGQaXfiuBzkAMDNdjIV3GGRENVySYQMKEoimQyJHsj@wmKv7adfPz45Pv6MuMC6Pw/yzDWQelV960eP9uSDw8CGn@@QHyJz6rjyHlKtJR/OpQZOxyCWyI9gXAURL3DDc52uY8n7tDsRONzAI9AgJvuqtOXjR0twng@dM54yqsWokj5Wu2sw/LqJ2WN6rQ4mvccSlCumJ89oRG/X67V2bUSaI6CIQayvMfr0xwLMgcfzHirroOjneNbR92jXMpfVTm0WmwGcdo1J6quR03ulpbrVHn7U5H7tPkautuHdqRo1w3UdVwQBW6z2d@za1Pb0vvHMcFENzcHhJvAXeAAy0WdGcpM19zH0Hgovl1LdZfYiZ0@no4Qu1TvJZSec4wsdEDmJrweFPqczue2aKF5W@zWWeAlB34Dd3WSJnnw/uZOrAp7us3YSnDKv@q/6TGOFXJWEjwTCgq5E@MFy6yxZq38NXhz2SaUCufEr@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@JAXeN31R0RmDGxIpY1DLAgjXSaOhPkDtixSwHZRJYDafdcuDy/3K4LXxGe4xnZbe0l/oovn@we4u8r4FQGa@nlkxeHLw4fCkyhDa3Ad1Y3qnK1XQWLJNfvCbEKY0BJm74eMGWDsS@7VTa1XX/J3008pgFwBdKa32At2sJmmCjKsU9Qx8QOi0MZdHfU0LRsq6EVYewDahoE1TS1iktEMTwIItehMmbnkL/tVB2PZ36Nzed6Sgrk/7uMDVKbFX7OUJtrWwwYGInFTk826uWtVPxZJZuKP4hnc7FTqJTNekqdx1NbKVy8VVJq5oRtlLZS@fzWnexW/ChVKQ3SFTWFTw2elTiTNmL32mlczit7SYFqgcWuzEHs1nYHR7tVVi9pc6W6u1eNvWyLpWKWH3msayk6Fso2g9OlddR19hKn2JsCnhWIx87jLBa/hJ8Qu0cHVDV@QJXFwiOquN7trwJlcwWWjJWTvq1YjnmJcAnmK/F7sTiudFQ8712MGk5w/u9rrzRoszHbCRxAjsM5NhhT83lcDogpr8be51op@@Tg0H7gPjSEWHPjYsPBxRm22Mz4zv7464yNAalx1qzFZrWcv@9erdcldVtDlXxFVoFho68WpMxFnXeMOnkUNPB5/0s/yM22S2DXMirYNS2f0up1dUuDgo3ff/H7qFzpfP@T3ccsjlP6f/cnP9KKf/cn/4q258UvaZpfyxZjEBKNaqEYOz8fn59fwsX98rFW7NquhBbgR1H1cnFLhtIoJR0MbSXG8QiMUlFNxjwp5u/BLOSlREJVtORWtpRJgs@FrzwtoWVKYA1WushJLOTFZGz/yMxr6r3tHSjZTjanVTegLtXwsDELf9uGV0ap8cmrC8bA0q33BgNTI5OisMo7afsdk7bZO1xkeidtsFe1Ou6qUPGIcrAIs4VHNnHlMl5PKVtxBgIWqzcuq5etFK3ikHT6cstuXsFDcwOP2iw7bdnwM7Y8@hkGWcnBA2tgM7Zee2JiK6kovZ54fS5u22D5OjSVLWVxkJptBWsz/CdJzeT7X/oNTSv83Z/82kX7ov2ZBkJquVxQtdjPfrY9taee0av/DADcoFInEDSJ10TdN2gIBVTGtfaafqzQIHdBNp7ayIzz8IG4igIqA0bGHNhGj8RV4RSZL6rZNtfq2EtQsC3UuJEmZp60qCWrghBwvZxZdwfdNMFgW6hqutFKCufCV9ELxnYGDH9V@OoCFDiMYDR3um3PmrpjOqqUoHhqK83uQhRI4auoMXODNIX4A4MEFFLZuh6VZ9kjrBGjxkaG56H@TRjThK9CFF8fvzVnYx2V2mBI04aRSMYglE/y6DUg7RakbfEIbXJNUOl5gDTjueORbGDoha8Cb0JYMIFlYeY2BKgCWfkqIADKkPABmy22zbJJdm6mUtWFcs9LPNGAJ3f0QKGGgNEQWg8VuASRqxgOnECQwC9AY7vwaxg4xohjAITD4PsSaiCKYHSyIRdIGm8@GBTAIu1yCSoau3t3katazewlGZUI4Z@YY5xbo3qwV@cVgAVi3J1eRUwzVJtaDVzDZgcYT1F2odVJXF9qNRKViWi9FAT4f3CjxRZ5parIo4oF8OuL94ouoAwiI9p5HXbZdo2pWjHJwsx3Ie9dyhSpNQhl0@bsjqx9FnheQg5/Fgu@rwZE6zg6X@m326saVRhw7lP8uBXq1ePEwNeEwjXnIfE7mASxw1hQFNOi0H3TBamJNkwESjsTWTWJ0RZKTikfdOZAyzHc@p9P4otiYWgGbx2VT/rpbJDSrK4DFeqNHZu0VZI2LTx3AS0CaJSv6I9ne2qf4ccQ/bqhyNEceaTkD1s@5pi0bzqoloji4gaEjgvSdYCbNDMGMuuOekwrswQ1NFJIaIfgkhSJMtwB5htx3LGMEWTpuWHQgUGvoigDYMimHdLK@MSEdjV8aMIIZHvKA45g5cw8MZVj1EouOX08V8h13MSQh8Pux/c6@BoQLcc5YZZ5YvBp6MSShiCPgfgBHHQaMLu4AbEV3HWjZdM4C6KmeSi4i/AqcmMpHYm7kZgnr7@z6kaijTV6QeONCbViGae6HcEvXReCL3d7cy/QMUaassAuhyTX8LUL1eKoNyRUmyX42tJqpKhLxuWNcUKMiYGWMTQKY9c4ZShBCzjGANHsBvp6sBdDab9KAwD1PehZqHx04lZQyxTkxO0lutD1fAJvszssqwkYkKuA89W1AQys@toydPCDqFgOb9KDipFpTh/pCvTOUQ/8UL@J3/wwftC60UyKYRfNm2344HDQobRqjHeLwJKPWLB3YHumom@AZwFyuCInGwkxBWBTYlLkoMP4V6Pz1i4QLamw65DSDCH4qAYoxCroSHJQu2Tkq4UCeNzXPf5pG1816dnZmUz6cqeuKRsefsnPc2zdUsYDEzhiR5kYo7H/zXSzq4wDuAuTxD/gKY@H450Z8rW18t05fwtC36v5W5ES8b4Xx8HxFD9UNxiRbj1UaudRg3po0kcuuwl/ZxRvf1orfR60vwq2P6kUv0QgjCGYWXqe7qYBWLrTPUn3z3pV3@OUOiQAh1o0AkfUYu0GlpEXmMxxPwzhTJCOhl4d64QWiQGSyKeLF0nzEgYh54HVt4/NGUSyjTO267r6PEH@SQyNDTgxJ7aHzWHYJx8wotr/c65S2Zw15q2l6LMwOgxq4RYJFxXnCec3A@X6tdF/xv1n4D/j/rNFokGyjVmLs2TodInFwVaP@laDkAhmHoS55LqoFz4EGfhxpnIQGHK@5HYJd7dGsQN8cxvUYy1oGNAmxoBwI6E0XjYbzZbtGWdbrZQygMYuEiKgxgF0o0U4PeuFZsS@dWqNHW/JyUY1uzAq@flGp@7Qbw28rWAZwwqihsHxZaJm1MHI38vBGQK/wAAB@TDwRNZgd5Iwk9VQoTt5QsNpiAsc84w1/My0iPvyvXw3YJc46jlio4BaEUDoHhYJsgk@LOg5/LutAXX41HUgTBBWok9NjlBDX7wVB0xe6Sqc1lSpkiK5kqQgm4B2ZFdrV4sS@ENVNK54RYp56dd/NPsbXzr7fegXq3NPDZYPGFUh2lVw3yWwEH53Iayyei1Sr5ADZUu3DBdGrn3On/qjNSSzpQRiBk8Hi@CdmZPuMBGp/G6S1w@dOxVtsRI2hXmtBkWc13i35P0iQClHeBjN86PNg4bgx@cEBGBkVkYz/GizaLRZrcYJB5utiXYWyeSMMjnjUXjo2ZpMtvxoID0dBMMLVk8LuFPcGCoCPJUPo8AGjUXm6acGrri/Ru2huEThp7mgOdQK/DaELDa2s25rZeqNSKYjROsKAGyI1wD0@CfgK8JVgqdKoS2kURyVAY3iNr8ZcFoBDYxIcJVr2E6EjYxkYGD4xRSNA9B3xVRDEFWaZsZfht9iOnAMbvW6Y2Y5pLrsmElf@f2DOLYQs5EOGuE@1EwOCTJKMi9sXzVtlOeIsd0pCDjA1XXOHJZYwWyDuzL1oyody@koIx13zuCHobmrPJ4nA/kBF2rY/9vd1223jStrXptPgchOm0yoPyd2EjlyR7blRLsTO8d2kp1x3Gpaomx2ZEktyj/qJHudcy7mBWbu5xHmVc47nKt5ij31VQEkKMmy071n9qzJ6rZIAigUCoVCAShUvRj0R8Go//hxRRZNEbPdrPplzRCd9vqIJ2d52Sddr90P497yiDq11T/tRXHoKzhA/RzqZUeoY4E4tp6sH/ux42gbLlnGArTwFVTdZjPqRaNm04VppFdJDMTZUhLsubzsYP1LT1Z5Ek8a6N7A7Z/8GrZG3u0wETJCFzuMWp/dvYFOhLONmiIZ1iL9n1LPSINRcT9dObI7eqjSJyOX45@c9c/7p6T1XcQF7MM6E@AbKWwgFAwGjIuvAixpK1bgEB4lbssPPF30p@8uqn5acQMvKb@SBZAhhq@GkzQGZYczqmveWJ0UM/UdfD@@Bza@B/Px5VX4JM6yNK9K4vdV/chNIVDGFI1Ht6OBppPcak@hk0El@Qy9SgrcGcU2W6a1gWmNstZ09kKH@MNP3mJ6SxB/fxP953egKV6/a/cFNOzVwZjkzTmMPMVRTmzOW13K3vAge6arS1h7@451UV5EX96BCkFqLAuuHjxp08BEvKY42UA2gG/heRiDTfE9W4hVJXEGTsNLX31eubmLtpvtsBuMw7arc/oWXNPifVqwsby6W8Mh6Fjo9WWt59Lc5SWpNI2D6JKpcgPLBP6l593MVpIlSriHd8oZw8bN9EP6lGjGFl9VdqtpHbC8vIjt2MsI25@IUyXBGroS/1HLUZl/pCfhO@N2ghAdZPYs@2m13jzxue8mTbrDjJDkLWSbDF/qBiLcYk334feR6PaWUudahaqml51smKLZPR7N63GLKwxPyrHT3VjyNqa7M89ZrCbAUhG29X1TyBRkGIm0Wq4NUb7M7bF@b0om4Bvv0/VumFWaMwRqUpIl3Sji5TbrF56DlXGDfrHh9J5@AfA0HDWFoUzbsKelQyorTjkPBpbWor@Qkk5QLCoKyTUaVi7HPFP2L9@SOls31tmaqrOVqTMZAdkqrUxOK1Ol7gV0z7wu6Iad0Q3SGUlYO9PPPLFN/3r9YIjdii/L0XIl8tXy5XKFBPJyuFypuySUl9vLlW1@iJcrB/zwebnyEz2kY2v563LFDAtkGNIrP7zAdy3C8d5army53jdnFHwOY1NvYbmS9Cnl@VFemSJECrSbtEYcsfX6upmjYUgTGyuVvgLHxD6WT7wP4/P/JfpPAo9xSCIkYo/zAWdWD1U5M2lYM4bUQ9OGCXkxYyRX9Gxe39thI6skC6p5SGs8uwyDJzV8cTkrjAQxpPKJBv0SgpCbldkYKWsmuyM6unbiUO7kbP0SJ5H1gbbL6UeU@TithKPN6fKmv7IgpAPvhicK34TnFDqmOsYIZ7LeDLRA1F@W5zQKfZ3FRfe@3UO8153NRNjmTRbpJQZryXTS4fhwjiNN9gdZJuFU2PdHdhnelJNBCe6dKMZSQY/MG5L5s24ZBIM9@L15zbHKAbWMCELiUelYRlkyL7AsRlIq6yxNVQYfoWDJHBrhYeszR/Lb1o@cT8SNz3PFTdOQKStVsuTKikkqXIAvsItgJLUni9c6PIR93/LVlLzGXosLAFbJpBaRr/3v0N/7or8bhdoQYaKCWYr17Kl0Wr2eO8tOYN5Nq53uQCT6atubqRwlNaQkp9WBpZnP47UpFR8mH6LkS6UJ9Alt35AtWRPcQrfJtYXAgpYwvMx@/LxCHz@v3EyoaY2ke1kwSksBNWk40vAE07Rp83GVhs/qYqTw/nbQ/e4OHmY72O48wOMGDCdILqN8eNFjK5d0bJPYli8QqeWKEkHOx6VJN6cfSdzz0W1ybEsf9pr723u7rz/SpPvkyRNPz9HjFD@MWuy1JvO4QGaL7WQ@mLFsWfERbguH3diOj8/6w9G9T73clCwRYU3KQEC1GPbTY9zTssyS5xNjl8pJXouiGtbndBgEGakEVSfAlB1puo6IIOHIfRBoIEa9JXr7vFrzOLBUs9kLzsNmk6cvEw5ez2LoGnMi7v198V7xIh5y2HOJinblOOwrQ23vqQ@vaofq8FVd7bzb@kl93HunPtR2D@H14O27zdeNLUX/13cP6srJmOIhgiQWlETX7bAVIi6wWimVHiuGvNUfjEXuuFuefD8IztWrfivEMdXzODh/cSYvhV442pBSdVqOjrGHGXHE0PNoBHsLDnFJy1goN22@k4grBoryntCa9hxr3vN@O@pElNfB2ncQhbG5xqa6EfUgyVtzk9sXJQnRLNl0iKPUwgLriooHlB9nNwQmEPsrkBg5JPxlu6A04ZJ/303Bw/r@mwMFBxpbe7vbjcPG3u6B2tnbp9e3Hxu7L4mejYPD/cbmOyRxxjd7242dxlaNPwgCpYKCZ4tfL@LRXBQKyM5UaX3GyXdhQN2fvGV3vaHBq6uAb2fGavmiB@kTBd3o97C9vO5cxFBfcCOUjwqUu1Tbf/me5nwV/oYTTnMUzPYHuXcxR1hdKqnnXBsNlg0ab@t6uNK0ly97fB5xPlYIshSus8cLl599ZYCzEU87ClVuCzYq2PsWxxg8lg1oqugewQYoY7BSVRwcbXnZf84gN6i2VrcP/6pSmxgR6hcUfWFMTdYdppi2lQFQXKJo9LAfVF5PPhDf04cVXe1oKBnUo@SDZFCP5QNU0QZsR9SqznEx2ruAeFZr8uHX88EOHwurJ8mHzYBXsU81TtJv3KWBSoJLwk1Il0PgyS4Ph@kVry8oEnN@hIfrdmVghBKYlGSiHCWybRvlzJGw6eCoQZu9ScBvpBI3wE4o6Ixi5Va9gjqEcVDYiyT44Gk36IkJVGq6w7ynnsKFU1Vf/o6SoH18LWXQZwZEwNAsHkm5ba0VhnctRyU3p2oMtI0kB841Jmi3IbA5hcAfAUOA8pmVTotnKr4wCzD9jmZlN@4TR2Lf9m92fmLn9kUrzBTQVlvur9Hvv3uayH5mnWTsFBk76qLfwyGplXyU2ekPaYyzWOUwZ5CCrbP@YBRJH7rZFvCJE09zlBsTG9X2S3UjUxvoMFljr9@zKj0hLr6h1hNiyrvUyhwvZ@eJ@ErjXxPn0yQsdndAJzjpX4bW2ZmPQ6SrENsvpAjzWTk2P8cjxkT0TyeVHX9TCJv7tLqxvfkp/7dffMTOFbEgoauN0SH@J8ZEXTQ8@JyPDRaH0Lv0SDMxD@OLE5TWNnhaWmKUG2C0DjyLaF33ormepIm58fR3XNmZ/M4fv36tSqk8JJOOdx6fual089WRqdLnMsdKm4BYspOQJVnvmi8@w0zk9Qtc00EvwMVQD3IE6/aJiIJahJjWnVx0SLLowM66uxP4ntpgiwqjSIpXCLs/ij@7m9WHG14xNShRFjldI6J9A7nseZZZCs9XU@C254Mj@X13cE/nYifTw3dB254L7btwyz@8GZZMSxasu4P92xywMrn9IbDUdv9mwDJJTkNLOD1hTn9pMbGmnV/jL1N9x2OPwGDuxQ5KAtSq7aLHR9TGW7krBTwbTKoQHRxu1/f3VU7WJ1SW5B6WDG0tBgH7nnqbWttGPRZ2hURpShbLifJkvmQs2sy/eYN5JvFuEBVaB/E1PRJhkfpE70TXIvX0zMIqBFvfs0A0lMti98XIoPhIA/5Ga0BCNu00q4HOzGYuyuQTxbYRuKabL7qxbcPPFtYydyNc8nBsA7JtgoJT3CyZ3X8fRD@umHpEwYJ7JTS4TZo0zTe0TjigigeUsVDI9uCcbjFdCiN7UbAXDe1g@FXKath/nqGYkUQJF13YEutaOdaoiX68ZNQcNkjENBDA0lMnikUzJRgRz1@e2x3qpZOem52CSMlEAN0XNldQ8eNvegpjaiTzZDVRyO2xtsTYHBksj7E7q2Gv35zpPmyh1ybFw2RVJG3nVpX/x1Qls0SmJkPzmY0xiQR5bXX10W2wJ1thiuf/LGyZQybl5@h8QOv7FGQ8jnl7nzi3seub9JQB5pBOTOvNgJkoSKrOjDkl03aejGz8CBfZFyJk4PEfMYkna/XU9QRus6HLjGRD5yxTbbCGcNJQGTVT1P82vzoI5Fvru/f99clgQyaYDn6DVf6b/jAO01t5lt8Y6xPu22e/hcNhj7PJfaZzQHH5GtPcy3Z8204MXqVVSOTzNrslHX07ScxufbPXwJXw9mIBYcixu7c@ub2XL6/bTd1pvK6rB@xYs5PZi8wNc54le@5FvXkIsAzmfQlMH3yH735cof8JB9@AJDLxbT6XaePdihtThLTmI44Bpc1CtWwtT/Z@J24FPXga8XP3Y5Xzf6CCvAtb39vxZu2sl9Yz5Qm5eNBzqZSfyxdyXJS@YUMXkLIgpDfx3ZqwcFPDWEries1pH/ZRONgKr2X3jC0ng2L5aWntmcOt6/kj//zo2bH/oFXNKZp8g955fDG8an8@7Z9ddlRXDX49uW6Nf/9NqdXHcJetVn4Qd8jltWqRHco@UfCk/azEnKsR/JFdOyMsdkHiBSu1rNJ1@Po95fEDL5oruCExwaXqwbnhQlyxG1XPj9aOq71qaf38qHe8jkt@o4fV0cPyQxcffqBZlGSMnMwfjY4xp9q7rmHvUsGHKMel1VdDFF8NoS9vgmHUf13bfZnZjYMCgC0wbevNG@oSgnwB1my4e1LohVeu3ibzFTjWgYLkLPCtoDLuufN@MrZj2hFhRr3ikzYbX/PfsecslAoXg1GfU4zjR7CW@hp9dRbMNaYS7yhQlqPIuIfE/QKCk@ZxcTAkX8diRZ0vi7pWxt1JzwJxhJIsDnOfcjncKQSi@i7X0bETF8KgdQYkuqRWf@Vi6vlzhTditbjAu3gw5QiGfGGidIxHHIDQz4BPG1AFa@4xX/twqPl4L@NBvvAe1YjvybCBvMOaIlJg/q2@8P0mLv@cCCCEXxCdq6C3OLXmRYqk3B3kzQV4Vcsu/HHMgGuV0ikLaCxgS33VFDhbijONUK0mE31fuAI5hVb0T7cgX@a3qWYk@T3JziThc2r9FoOW3KWctIGfblrMtYrlTTGT2SLFwq3UwE4XLY/ehDSsxmor7HYJaaHFQkoOPPL9Xl3/w6T@@Ah1HifIS3p@Kj2fSS9IuiCV5irQBJ9mqtiZcotf0nzfVC7N5k/VVVWsvBSop1sFUknSvOvz8saFUb8ZpZk3kq4UrkwSnmcS8lbKzzN6X1LuZcokDJ6kH0m65u8V3fMJlpm8L7L149fRHRSy8ay2NZng0kIv6v7o6HDtOgVsliNqKiXFOXqmMoOqqu9ganFCGhz2@XnYblRTKA/LRuLwmMltPH@RK2gl40d3Eg25xTg1sGaMEYtKXOdDJtw1X1ikejj5ngWCYYLRlBm5G6bwWBceW2CR656pVm5BTg1watrkEK/iXuRX/DGDPYucybc4O3FBML@Wxsvt5iyBWOjey80mU1aa4LqIfNSNmjOLpHWPJyHOFhK71i5wUmcod7A72Aa/l8gJW1AYSTFF9yRFUzrNUDbse1MXIvGb8/fiA@dlQDr2oBteqxqWGQHfwnIyF9xHYTyK4WuK3eDEF4NBF6eOrPBd8RVq7eF/ZRXHLSlEa2YvOA1Y9kh@H0/6QjoVKqg9QL6CgUiaEF@cnuIyGW7A9q8gWrHjEo0KTq03lg0NGjOPVuSaeajgfIMFcDc6tZGQnpPRA0rHg6AVFhzS0WLSfhxpaifSQWd5Px33RuDSjKa0iuP8y0XU@rz1Eue5T8qlR2WLZJf6OLhUePQ4vWBFRDIJK/BKuFp@7DjW2XBLzobzAOir15jo3xNvhpdhrxc6NZoxOGNMSmscDi/DdsFx9sPkEBhwwco4mcQ97P7FsCWbO6R0BcSMuCUc@3IcRhyGX8zPclzc4rMy38GhVXraTF19GbVBQHPjpNPH6TAfWMBNgNADhc7DERHlgaeyKPHZs8aFdZdzbEQRNeDnxDqbSMjQ64@iFvUM72Q5XQIlxyBpZb32BCZUX6sb4HJwYRYCuB6TUsAgYI6S5uHg6EPz78JB6YaZM/bA9EyRpF@fxwoN93AYkfRNCcy9wsUs3KmDD181DtTB3s7hh9p@XdHz2/29943t@rba/Mhn3DgoZ5e/6tXea5IuyWm6nJrv0Ydc7YBK5jjBqe1@VPW/vt2vHxyovX3VePP2dYOgEfj92u5ho37gq8bu1ut323z6ThDU7t6het140zikbId7PtdqijlpObW3o97U97de0Wtts/G6cfiRa9xpHO6iMpzq19Tb2v5hY@vd69q@evtu/@3eQV2hYc5242Drda3xpr5doPqpTlV/X989VAevaq9fTzR078NufV@xkYDVys06YVnbpCUsauJ2bjf261uHaFD6tEXEIwRf@@rgbX2rgYf6X@vUnNr@R18DPaj/yzvKRIlqu/am9pIa57i3UIX6Zevdfh3uk0CJg3ebB4eNw3eHdfVyb2@baX1Q33/f2KofrCvn9d4BE@zdQd1XCEfJVRMMohal0/Pmu4MG062xe0hzxru3sHfwqJM/EGEIyxoV3WYCwwwCrSUi7e1/BFTQgTvAVx9e1en7PmjK1KqBCrCo2Dq0s1GFRMRDu5lqt/7ydeNlfXerjuQ9gPnQOKh71GGNA2RowCDjI7EOVfqOW41@IrzkkZjVMZzrc3eqxo6qbb9vAHOdmzjgoKG5hcm29UrTvAD/v9YmStTHnkFwbm@sdKY/XYbweDm9IzN7jybxmLS1t12nGVk7u8qlCe9o1nk64UrJTqOZJkmk14zLmnZ4cnHajHqdPu6YJsVk4@M8PvUR@8hDHJhPzpzQY3p/hQssLjab72tNWugeNJuef5eSGTRuK6G3wefl8nQbEe4BK29s/FQqQvfnGUJt/KAPOtlQDwcQyCnU/0FM34Lz0FPFYjvUxXB5H4DN1lEsxyZnOEoh0ciXHRHAJq2Sdyb4PdLswAVdA77QamKfFJaRnKkf05/e1/RFJgfrA0ln2e4qFrGIZTSi30NTjVTCLhH4j/ZIEHW4ykIchp9P3ZJdHdb8hdN@v@16ninDeUe0Djx1vVuKn4SnE8Xzk@UZWT521pESYrPuZhUmOX/WJFO6XwpDbpmLP80R/3gGG/H5gF1Troo3q/WmpfuDFIdFkq@0awtcr@BOhs73pvbXxges5korj9cnvr9KvsvYgr0gfOPShHfE5Y7559WxZKABxr44iCSR9pBRLFpljL1JkvmKMp4h01XUhuUPzdVnIc/rRBJSZC@Crl0nZuNhdG1jT3L45X7tzea7nR0SncD28dPVJ2vrTuJ266@@/H5EPey@lr2ODWgeJz2Nk6xRskWKD48Uy3t4yv7MwMUiMsJVvOk0/gg/D4ndRtaSCYIMzY0RzakHE71cCDrkFDvguOcYfp05MjUDuJmmemjNeXDNKn5AuhLzgDZm6Y65167xB7CT4W@GeNIgzUCaxdihL3EurS5Y7uV2jKkoL27YcQ@yFHKGj8WNW0ID3upi@1ncruU3zdtWL8Ziyojxyt3OJQmJe5NYKGNX0ZOR/Zb9jOgNYPYeRl/@qvmNHj9qB3fs7i6IR7XRAZFxJymJfep0M1o3@khDPkboDjhVMzU9V9jl9zRSPPb0dnLiGMQaDYwK4tDAxjcLeD3xIzJZJVvAvlj21BfhVDjvAJx1zbH6nTh3VnM0lHXjP0S/G68USmAlTk6EaldJHY7J8jHxY2HImSHTn6IHw/8n0mQG/Oe04iToKbUsJ4B3oiRDFVrR8pWJEl2ZgwbrdCOlpv3pYwrmm90xZ0nD9OnNtdyvIRLo3hmbDx/Z7WHHnUEAMDk2Nuzxm5iknQW0dHqR83RxnJP0WucDV@m5wkwVU3Dza8c@q12@OVvBi6c82WuyKnxNRdULWbid8KinJdPEUl7dj3MCzjP@P4oPeAMkGfDMpWditTrJWSU9yowc0K6WrAmnnXhMIrX0242ndg@U5SIzI/v1yZchFIHeAD7T7eQYJn0l5rlZj4s8E6tD9oIHJ@VYJmPy0S7rTtgQsxsCzv02b4YgzMnoChNEV6Czq74UmnLvs6EIKkmtDlM/gxC3XoFIy9PqVYI970yCQxPs3/XEP34ou1omR0EcfGgM7evyBfUmGBPK3bs1W1is@OCg78N2EZXJtoQuj5AurX5/SKpjgHYTjn409grqg950CHvxxVD7L6T5LBrqHQmj9FM1UJtk9c7TjDimZ9TiaITbCu0C8wc36TyEhai4J7nOrymXmNfw6IbZdIyuH5aV@zxNeU40YbekTMTnak19/Sq5hKDaZWjIFIziZHHBNptcD84dkuF31R9@xtwPFajXDtuJZ1ILJO8FSic1euzjsTWSpg/6Me9oUFdgByShRFk20hJDVZqjn2h20nZNudQ7JnyXcku@v56ESY21FFWUMq6unZhvLU@dCSqtaNegibPQ8soqozJrwfXtxsUYewvNHlur3KdeIlIqokRU7xvVEU8iN5Onj3jSm/zV@zFGD33BGbdWQYEwdFacq07LOcYPNgUfonDYtvdESZNpBwNsv/HSp99jXjRbh9rtXysYxeGYVgCtYnRdZBhN9y/9s15zq98NTqN@FNA6DV7lr0Xi4XHMj@iw02H/KuZoRRKC0crUHqfP4l9G3LDhPTmXXLdcc8WjcODaZgqj4bh2Jm4ieOccRoBpiFXm78Gkj7SkzOPVtJCTvX/K9nhlb/3Gso/KswrLiT4AaAG3MWFBIXdIR3wxybp8uj6V4WReBgvHE5VXgXeDxV4G42dEIj6GyWBskJkyS7AbgZXZjRgfta/9NvsgHMLRUrgdIsxO7PJnP0CYa5IiP8JSoKLKT0tWUTlFuYYfQjyMbyb3ypN/MvaEwJ9Av/xoFrfMYgQWcR3jbSmW9Yr2Mkq4sHlgxDKaJTFJseg06lnXDzmmxfUk1Gzy@CZqsOUPKUXazd4UV2JEurTwQVA9t0kipzn2MKksq2WP/XZABamN3NLNDBveZj/Lgx@HuLJzBsG0pSG7FtI3kapFVEJc4AnzWhtl8al8@4hZWblrr00QsDrL5MwKaO3mjObCN1AimV9xrNUfkjDOTVBPm3osx6P@YPmO1LtRdsz0zDaL1i3Pu9UQWJitSpPlgzaTtjrG43jdmcRngmmyFGNLM@IhLF/5OWHzSSJeV5sYb9Xm@BY63ESz1G4qmVSS/m7L2MekeAmLXjPRJEOKcYeT0vXk@1GTGt68WYJomLK8arLEaEJkNMfyaIGaIFNCpbtTiLlP4z5BjzZRDvW2iXZ2/9xI1EkjOePy1CRlnFyCnnDcjkubJJcGHRhfwE2caLiJkEoUzmt/zEd55fwJnAwjQQBCKw7z6T6U7OCmnTXBRxwdoOM2YS1UhiSipw3bwiFx@p8QjL3y680dbfHQHOfLx@sC6TqBRKsKzjUPkrlvTq9HzWuGMkUKGuIzSJG0aEo2nd29VX@2LZSPIEhpTtaWviUfjfHUQ8KG/thJzWvowGlVumRmRGUHQpNFA40FWqWcdkNZrkL7i4bC8bBu0MOIFhDy2cXPQ10C7rzXSgm1UeS6PUYWT5NbRpun8htSJGUoeQf59VAUVZcXrgQgFIypfLVMEODWlLHHoQC73rE5L4Oo7iMqWC1jWNJH9oqa2nnOSAdRdYbHq1aO0qwcz2wY@ZlASLGYnSdFhHSW2VlSKDTRzcTFyvFkdnvSHKQQG94XilNX6F7J0jDpOSEgx7UuealEOSorv6Q5mBMfr3qZxIS/OfVZyUotTaYSfRIMj/LlydSnpUxqptqVlWzRTEmih2fXmkkkUng2wolU@HP/@GqK7fI8sQm1FhkZLUPbZyPuOK0yad1W@DVWz/lSttExDDz7ZrhZfjUlxErGKft8B@xqmY8M4Lv9T7fWWKYaTHSsAPZLZy67uLIgZI01h6kezcJK13jaSxwUmDVtv6PeH@7sZNy@noyNodF5OFwtlUpg4hPb@b2xrcZWUtQvZnMXOxfdbnFw9Zfh@5Miy/4w5JAAFbOCDqlLaFDEhf7wVCJDAAfKitx5fZEVa/2LTscOwYATSnQedZvk1N4QFE9AUWL08v6QN4AYpJ5gf0ED0b5fVDL6rgJRNDUUcwxFpWESfJkzp2dEHnzowD47OaliYBDMxpqJ5i2vuvEFMwgim3Bnsfti70tqnpx7FXa7fV99QLxjeApY@DZZYGfHLlCSLDhh5Nu9FzH7o/VVeBl1rXvFyGLzOsCZicnEmTB@4eEbfz88rV8P3NzRzzmaVqjJD9HMh/BP7avcac7TzuLvAFb4kNC@U@7zYOC2mE6TmWmq1yM4fSKMHpX9mWufTBaP98Q0zW7PDaLORrfAzhqo6R7rAsaXPXcvt@SG7Alxc5@uyx3QsCQwNE7wuXK3Erhq9s8Ti5ejTuduUpHDAEjHfpdElEgof04g8hkAj0A9/Iie8KL9U56G9c6EQxFRcBCsY1ruoEATBRznfqv625Vbq9XU0uDhQ1WrbdJDPq9qmzW1jQ@bm2qb3jfx/kN1ZXV1XWTutveFPm6aj9/UJsHgHc6HrbPhNr1SWhX3xmCtjS5eKlaX/PWlZvX5xnpcPKpt4lo/Pf3nv/3X//z3/1as6Zf/gZdNfjn6OclUKBSKS60vSz98W8f70fbx8tLJ0dLgePl0HVz2d/Ya3m@M8kFqPloYnjiLMgtYX9mO1Kyz2fuMLqpMTL/zYPiZpEtFLbbi4qL@GkvkKJaxi63Q@h7iHuUJLeFN0IHJpTwhsUhAx9iOp95phTDAo/mGKEm4wA5UysvZitm4hzuYJENyqrKoPfGwznoZ4k5L6kkBd3FpxspHvTjsYQf8knVeaZ7jBPQbjZqaf4s/v4lPN/vX6sEnVz0oqQe@epDL8U957Rl99ZaKEW7nSjZaDuRyPqWkRwswM1RxxIoerx841s4EuR1niUP2AJJxU8GZ5Racn6z@@LKMBFyLT50FRPZUskXCh0wosvhlqfeNuuUL5fiWy1y1YUWhqVcxXJl1opL0L1SgIBZDgLTmcyFIpU9V4qSPbyTjqWi@6L52OJoQAwZZ91/u8LjHB5qLlnra5jmzlkKYIzafl6@YG9flMjSjjRSpP0WAD1RkOVnim4TLi8uOWHlbreRmyi1su32a@cTWYRyOjG26FPqbsphArLltwi319L0WbcgtxysqFyXHK1ZVuUnbb@VYRc4vuqNooK8rcO0YUF@S2r7JSEKPMiCBIz77K9MjjDcKjKeoiW6RYFlj1e6j6TISevpqOnWwV5CTI4sIxZ9dGttfJ8a2V@RbIoYdhAcYqcSUrxNE3Vh7XRkysU@D4QmiAwYdDqg2knMz3s9DhNYJjPudBOkCQ2aT83Q8U1MWB8Pg9Dzw1eJu/3AYjBs0bZHmM2oVPGohXDABCQw@XfWs5hmEpUW6S5giSVPYcgjBC7pjHR5N@jaX3DlBl5qhoN2uYBBk2IkpGX7N9NUEHVOu/o5OsFGeEt7JaaQWsSx5YWmkIeXsazM8zKaGjmNqsMdOMnByjqCajEzDC7rQBSbacz74JUnehY8AXXdO3wLUVxHWnqF@zE6nYS/ITE6DrmMu@hfXlcyLGM8cilKskRwN5Uk5jXgHrEiP/DnrBULmJuPOyFlw3YVPsQ7ntmjPI@zkO7HFLwYqSgLQcQAzvhmi3vUiEZYTM1QaA6OgGmz5TxA63eCU8BtfBWOw4qdF98d7Re/o50@94wfup97XT797jIkWyWaWzatFfZhtJJYeKzQzFv3Mq7FKi42rwU@9bIZPPSV3WCwSECJF9@jn4vHXIiH0aRGh7j8tCkEyXQZMivPrKwJ8cQrNxSwWxUVnwXvgmc53fyx7iuZW/kUfygdPfgkLs6jkbXpa5ww7BIrv6f52IVdO4uLTldLjlfJjWgmdhtf5YXiB@TYfX5yE16RKxFjO0tTz6fcMN2QI8e06Dtbp4zW1U8KayN2TWF9S0iJUD3Oux0nYisoUhCcoP1GZ3aXiiouX5Alw@IgFv6@I5Uxe9gUlpoMW97mYP@P@OeoJYsi1ydshwpGwMhAbEd5CzQOyCb5yE4d6Zrgs8z2ngtqC71YGQt1bXLRmi16/l9fKmldYXocSjVsz3aelp6XJMTo1RDMjdEkrU8v3VHnjxyf/8d/3flscLW6sFD8M6Xe0@Nvi2tNFeaQHentk3i4XNxafI9vat8VxkdbA9PjkP/4nld/4C8FByvg5/dlYNbDWxosb@SoX@bq4sUYP5ZUVqvd//eu/UhuWZMWGWKxLTV8xYuuGIltBj3mX0lUDrZRl6XIqVvhiFmCIhSGtzekFhlHXK09LvE23qK0qLkPt@crYo@gpng2zRmwqJDsZxp6CNCMpUEUFeQFpTCg6yrLdMGYbYN4UTfXL/cJaTCuAX7Q5R1JlYrpxP4bJ0JIsi6gDXamR1vPysFH6MZeYd1RyxqZk3aiQWNppWfv00Tqxw9t@OIpaWSsJM1zPW8FVeFIAHxbC9gWtqXpxt//rsHhJLHleXnla7GBzv8h23MUBQ8oPxoXfSRHUwYBoYchGp74aUg/0z@HCy@doQaTQ7yRnUiaeJGnZg7Ale1jZmMSURe74@XI8jOYUUlXa5b@kwCNypg4EacVK@9Sjknv7FZV7mGSUfLzm9YDNWzaO1S4w8mINO2DZVHC4DdgdNO0p1IanfAmJS8HrumQpBO12M9BprrOQM6HSfGfhLOwOqrmOuHeH71ScmGj6i5p5I5R8hB2EfJ4FHWCdh6OAlujVHH/BejytAW5S9Flr4iouJWtH59Wr@naVo67MqfpKqr6iHoWWkNaT8IzljU3Z2US2VLFVOQybOFKbWTHVFpugzcMC/wCDWLql0cG1BN0cvgFJVEubo63K7G7zeS1MPHIVyp092VqUyNXOYnr50Tc55AY1dCfUW5DKSEDAC24FFsr0fiA3IKomzGjUc8Sf30Sy8e@hwXAb9uBK1HZbJ85HZVrqXSL2TTTiu5SKSKD9yto22I7MHgnoxMVWEoI2h42XnAeW6lR4scUZTXdUOAy0cQmVy8k@1VFLJeFlOzp6rQSKoA@5Unnl0ePVtSdPnyHK2YJu7WwwKFTAKmBwFhAM1qhdWmTje7WaW87JJ4Sgnq4S0GeBxQEczLquPM@4fb7y7lXLJQ2slGNYVxxGQ4rr7UoGmUIchgXMCLRGcYc51/2xcoSGHX9qe1/pf@Jv4x@QGc64ow2E9FY/vE09Uznn4nCgyoKZneK4j@BBxdMpdt6w39mHt4kQtq7C9lTRa3iAGJ0N@xenZzZ3FLRrq0MaMERw9kuNFdTLcJQ6GLOwgi6qNxwa1u2LqoF3NN0CGOViSoDOJ8BpmGm/lYG2NMXoWKZJCJ41cWMVR4iW6ajNzsydvb6q725PIrZoh6FjuAXbspWUO/ZkBgcyiNVrNfeQqKu9XfBVUi2T/IxXZRZwJeQr83X4AHelWwhEbVHFyGrWG0buPLKUmRdT16ZpUepH4DUDZrl0OynNvVbTChDECEK9m5QIMT85z7FJluJkdzLGKXg5V7FsRN9EccwO5nRlOU9blHImjiqw4NwAEPs2pZw0pFRBj/JjnQMvS28jmKPcisbWgDZDTlaq4cycHGaCrW5jcYCNqOOGFmh/Y3fLV9t1@rPzYduHorxZ@wntTkI834xvWeNbrqjGjukC21ss29zCZuo3XFEiZilph7EpghC@HYmKGKZeA@qNHU17GdRHmbF9nHIF2DXQSrjZHdWDBI5eeA9kQS/eE1ccfF2Hv1Vk82pa0iQuVfSwkC2u@QPboslCWmsCSUh5BxArkyASRy0pty@kDC8W6Kx5B3rtYhi7sTObpzMsKwsqUtt3ikT2LM/eSJl5bLGi2WKlgn6cxxfMt3N54yTs9PVdtIQ5buGNe3@MN/J3Z478/xfMUf/ncMcjzR2PKpA9wh2J23C@0clh2PszOOZkzHNwsx2dRtgf6livaETJtwCwwAOGuENKieUS2naDOFHu7ISHk/MRjIRWVnEx4A81/rFu/OMKZC4/bof/rzY@/w9u/Kpu/GoFc82MnteqneVu/R/T4lQldLMfZnYv1F3J5v3Rlq7plq5VMJvO6Ob/6y3N/x9q6RPd0icVeEyQAwdxXz@fm0UTqR1sNRqpuUXB0U67XMSxn82VHtZe7WqOFg@d7kV8VoW2rv4w/k81/k8hjfgJYehwFpHYhiZreVmeymV50Sx5l0PhkpW0RNprPKNb7dUTVroe0ROUCGne2BrqhQop5L4kpqdNhVR/TKVvMvncFWeR7TpYJg7OrQW0rAjLXjrERfPVQTJX1pJ5ZZt9IKutw/3XD/@LkOE8@KxvoRHy6NqrsNs1M4m9BDtMvE7pxljNAewDvebIsIomJyM70re9E3ZZuFmqsWOLiXlx9iJBjtpw/kdrqXPoG1ZUbmwZEW0KurxZVcE01ywv5Au1XTLNbrJu8R/i0meaS59V1L5eGNxEqkBv@GleTNdpK6ur8@YAKVXADwZgyaf8c0bV/wY)

Cython is separated from CPython with `inspect.isfunction(lambda:0)` as described [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/limitations.html#inspect-support):

```py
import inspect
print(inspect.isfunction(lambda:0) and 1 or 395)
```

Cython fails on `len[id]`, so `len[id]`  `eval("len[id]")`  (Whython golf)  `eval("2?2")`.
Space before `?>` is for Chip.

Answer (score 1):

## 396. Befunge-98 ([Hali](https://github.com/Deewiant/hali)), 16590 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S 11111111\)1 1>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse                 2222222222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&11# 11 393374366369375377370285329364392367372376289368371388   389284373
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'wWWWw;WW;(W;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__='''  
#'  \
__END__
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{


#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata;re7^0::PrullasgeEx Cr Uithary,8,3"t"F ._#^*2giogrlopstdisp[]!!?48[]?\在ｕg=1-2\0C05+---<?ML4oya:nlet d=/;~ ^ 5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'7* 001- #vk!>6*+'P:3+'D'34#v({057998ab-1f21-48d8-9b4d-153083943716}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}'
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5L39c@NKciD448TA@0eUQHWTFAmAAL9JkWq1Wv1ab7pbPWr1e8@PZLNBEiTRAgE2QEpkS@qYmb2b89jePe/seGM89vqNZ8974/NGrG/j9jy@tXcj7Ptxw7E/@Q9of1xcOC48/8FcZhYAghIp9RuvIzbuIBGoz6ysrKqszKpCoqN7w5/9LIYXe@ZY84HlTNjE8Cas55qnhiuz@3N2Tze9vJYVBEy16w6mI8OeeBUhxlTGLN0eTPWBwfqmNTHcNPMMg3UMyzmDeI2x7ak99YxeHXxZxmzjjB3YXbMHENjEOTFs863hQlyOsQeGdTG6mLCuMxrpds9jY9e0JxSbZ@yZDp7@tHvC9I43cfXuxHRsiCow9sK29FGnpzNKPnYNnqnIAFT3hPIsx5QYe@K4ngElOF3D8xwMLEOg7prO492nH11Jr2bYRzogNbaM2ZXiVZV9ahpu72oOjX1y/PDh1dAs@5rk2OzhdZTUHNudTpyDyVX4ebY7MGydaXJZ1q5GFoCYE8MqZUqZq1FFaE9jYnaXyoGIh6YLrav7rci6ug2thW25xYzReDJnEm9/3bLCtvWY7rGpN9UtSmdPRx3DDRJ6E92dmPaAnZmTIZsMTS/MR6m9sd41pJ5hmSNzYvSYZUImp@9DAdB2j50Y8zPHhSb3YTq2NYeMRtfsm5glwAMA4pWYDA0OZ6TPoZHtCXQOpjMP0LCMAFpSiEH6B0ZnOmDOdDKeThjg1jM9vWMB0M6c9Yy@PrUmadaBOCAyhZ8NDdvvzABOBhDHDsfq9ZRQMxZ9Xu/1WAb6MeBxYjATqEZoVVg2C@HMcYFqkCrAyAdG/ZrX0ZhBm0ET9Z0Ky2cyEL8fhiC2uuU5PjLLqGGkDWOV2gzhPnOdgauPgBo9g2j6ycEz5nUdF3zww7R8PN0EpqtP2PY2i@8/fRBn9bBZZLcjhE1UY@fQBLEgkp3q1hR6SLQlHGgfN8wtYJPFN@IVFgeyaBmWy7EcDNsS0/JAJDVTBgeMfy2rwq/AtBLLqTCC8iyrFeNpLKvv6gPTMjikAUIqYueHJBrcMzmWVUs85cCx@jxZlwossmyJFYqsmGdFuJdZWYMSEXyOqeU8/ArwA2hlQEeFXzbHAS36PvRV7G97rK@PTGvuQyfwXZZXWREgAs4qQNZKAAGe2Sz@svAjtJavKOzJECg@1E8BvGSZJ8iRjJApYTMq8FC2thTiish2efHeEIsH8gHh8iVWhOILQIkcoADU1UpQfD7DK@INDcvysw09zEbYFjPwA8yLQIcStEAGaJlBYhbhB37geRowNw04mQbMSQOGomngzmIRkK4AcQVozoJPr6HunUBBvBytR8QHrg5gVKQ2MjIViQQQoLVYFtqswHLQGbLYGfJZBvgDLsUCA15WUlkpx0pFBvQsZxi0jQp4YU9RgYeqgI@KwKD9VegAKuCkArVVAKpm80yIEFvNYjzkzUJeII2agzw5cEPDqQX8QT7oGSoUqUKZmlZedETATctDffNZ6qFaAVq3CHFANw1w1aA7aYCtVoJ4zFsCGpawA0O35YTQkQ7QKtjloR8CMfKAD8GFtODWillOP90aD/UOcmyes9PHrAUcCgUkI2TNYPXgmUNqAioZAIOjANDXoAdkacTAMxcWb6kApIHgjZ5JTNoygX@pIYWKaeqQr/XxZEE2tUAYjeeTYRim8TAHmKcJDNAY6N15GAmjLx1GLkILWQzViN8uAGVyGOoBd3WmnrUAEjpyGhVlnJrWIqxEYT1D7/VNb/hugWuOCukY@sQ2Txal5PPpCFH1SEQBI5aCitlo2okpwZQ1GKJrURetiGnGTthASyirKqHXMfpTe2BI5VIEP4qZTN0JTC6LMss82DUHA5iXF3DUNFWTJstFcJ4wtLLZiRAGInWxTNeEKfwu6w5BqAgjyxx@ubyAkdUQxlzv4MwugSQGM0EZ566@OWOdu12aORYIZolO3aE5DhJX1iaONC4VMisVIn2DKPe2lAlZM14t@bVj2ok4iyeFSwHmGy5dRmdrmNQ@xZkK517sujC3OiQ5LNhnwg5mxyQQbXmih5nXAjYKjdLVcRbGOcmgOTWAY05kBoWAKGg4pyi60sS4VIxHk2fHRUkVJJ2e4boM04J466VpmvWmHc94M0VZaoFXH@ZtA6b3vm5aIQI0j@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@mAWlsVEz2nv0iGxhAdhBa@6ihYpdfVGA8pioQKXSbC7S2DpTCKnTHcyKLEFvk6DuOjOE9x/CoszjuSTj0sTDPGNDQgHHWXzCjEQro0EttUix6wHn84YXwsUBhZWWwKL8XfGTYMHS60Cth0EPzYZvusj4o2hERFnUNvds1xhO/nzjEzkw7IvMfPkSZn0IlH5jsDYXNe2z7Sq@BpGHPiciyqAMh6mNfFdGR1/ravESCR6h2cs5iza8VDylOr5QuvsI0Sxi8EtfgMKYhgQoQMYnpBFkJckezO0ReOEFuQ/I2jDZ3er36EBYt3h0xqR@WjdiowHYEWQmDEI/1MCT4WdcByWMLYdWXAjDpUsAtoHVvtAKyEyJp9aKhsqLLwBRvAzpybGcFVCBmCBeTLMdQW1BnfI5cQ7fCzkjDxVtqI2TYiwUmnMhgDh2PHRdGBmc6c1pNoCaL9C5fCU@Ec0VSZveXp1aYMuI44U9wFoQMY0uHvoBDDEcqaFY6cApgYlxJBp7n8BIjCNOoJ1g@fmfE@nlngrnUtg1UznR3zoFA9WB6hoLmzHRdYIOnOEnwOSiYTGTqpzAn6L0eclYkB437q4XL2KP3ph1zdlUT72Kg/NoTTnWX9VEJd0HogEGUiPe9eLJK4ZQzEiUqzniiUFZ@FyEhJZKhyRN90OthkngIjOb53O4mxKUhJqaZOJ30S2ISHJiRy2jsY1AVrmKH6gN2mtEJjGvyVdkApm9JgruEYYQJRigyRuguyBkwCEHLLJd7HZ1dAPdwmTTb46pIoJKoci4sy7B7YVk@IRCXaH1lXoTndskhRWY1rAEmp5rTJLFEwA@kBGUUIUBR/LkVA0ja43Ek1/DAqU1rcSzBRZEkOw@FX5gAEoSMCcKH2TUnbV9cuXs3EFw2ajXobCBNAdvsJaMabbBoKQOnhsQySSN@IfLEeT7BsZFIQn0x8SXHBsQm6Km1OjufDF0YceS/FCARkFWwsScHhPXb@al5Mu1dbWgbAzGRiKMOhCazOxGrAkz@fDTUbqJqfImqoPXGkarYeTE/gb7WeSkUG1T0k7mGh@JvzUcl0sIJxMDvqytJxLP6YYsOvTfvWr5IwF0w2Dk36gD6J/5iVsiI0r5MEAzaayOVA8HhwOGwZ7vHj2r@WOSRSse0K0sBltPVLQrexORikPfxwf2j3aNfbK@AYZmdytUAxcyVCjjVTmfSwJ4qOVmrbEZhLAA/aN8MGzMupxEFP5pJziwiKs27MLnMAnIeHn3tKklAEkJyUAngxt8VkYanAaFL6Oje8MokzAapFBQZZgnSMumABTBDB6KO8XqAz7Pp27fYeFeRGvvhiJk11TmAIFA5sIN8MkZeEcCCqE6fz4iUF6RQ08bNhoUrmjLA5yOUmq8iQ6J0pMt8dPhw/6hGYP11NYmSKN4EZCnd7cnQ560pqOCr0gD7A1eXpeQF4ihPE64rCdztLhF40bZsDXwAgLqO7DDJGgVV84aA@97VulGo1A17APkJwlW5MioPdb8sohE8cIrrosq7ahaliMVkFQatnLHC2OVpq5vPG8VcOTptdRdl9qJAaWMA5oFAbnQh6sSTMEReSJG@WO2j//zxNcQ9EiJBFZACzDyLyVSWZwmovUgmi3vKHmhojmXInxLHE5mYVJR4sDcgdz1SPiPp92fmJJFJ8qeahLRQ@u7ugfYgSOwvWdNKBikNqIvjzOT2cY@v60EfsR3LGThsC/Jw6TAoEMSmtdXcHTj2tRbSMRCrGsNtQuC/uHCjj2GuMd@S4ki5ouoq33DUbe8MuLRayCKRiEIESqH08mv9VAdyLer9/ODzfZhE1HwmE7ozdAEJInmIXOjqRkIpgElQkOzjs7KC4ZbhtdEeREiRPTustM/owoy7i@iVgcQxZWVl@pUofexco/hrZ36la0EI71rgiJDs4OmzxwdP95/sftacaPn8kj@XKReAcFBeB2QhecjphqN1iw9NrBaCi8HYcHF4AReYgoIS7BhNPRcYt4xJZI7Aml7DN1sTHztDO@4lr1bmDGOl13aXd6EnOPh4Uj8jKNo9C5URl@9Y43yO/Wc4mYy9iqLAKB9OOzIorcrrrmPpA4XywcRgWYqKqsvBIa5reKtyADLe3OA5@OIWiA5zWkHUrZEDygvteyNrYAkOnlatLHMwBF0YN8cNNymHPZhqo/RAQwBdWQnrRgyYfEBb/xm0k8i79ldVrcT7tZrRcooYJFsa/pB2o2@A6pSA2QpIkbziZc27zbtsDlwaIV0FEmPyFi1yeAznAouBIEmrpqjnB8QhboHrpcgriEZvpriaC1xKyWdyRbWQV0AtAzUNZFYJ19ykkT7pDqWJIwE8yenTukGkF/a9rm735S3fESALct8dqGq28bLZtFsgoDfvEm6499yYtxpqK1ll17Ns@emTVei9S9XDvhsEQN8lJ3RNerI1/KynX2dnPZ1GV48pk9HYn3OkMXuyC4LUWwf4dc@Ijj3MoEQjla2ltAomfqesWBCyMKuAN6SUAgMKZlroegriJYHQi@Ih9BzgW5EMbLGaEQpM88kQ@EeWJfbIlbwu4WJw1ucay6jgorA8ngPLo0TItKUsIhREUIFjDgFRiYMKhBIPxsc5CvyYSYSVod6PQ8904h5t06BohQu23hjakda7uzhReLhEOYEJOhx8OFFA/8J5gp0ZcVzK1z2@YAqZ/KMGQX5QF0MItDEQLorb4eEK6IeUi1YIgHlB18aV2@FioRPXHaCzQ4GEE65/gBBj0wbGACoJmXlFdnlFeEkUslylE9s5sxFax2AlqWNO@H6DM3Vxy93sResGybMaTwPQqHKRqYX25jtGly/08sxUC9BDdTYyRg6uZoCAR9zIoCrofF8f1VEPF81hZGck3LQE@BK7tweMtGvwJStphHoc9Op9Fp@4yq70uaJLb2FA3SDeYeUjTew3@nFAgOVTFrRQ4y/CkoDkjCjRp7Tkg5H3A4nb71rYs0S95owN@6rayZXSRLJKpyHicb4PdR7f2NiIV@L1eBpcO@DaRtcOulLg2iGXRC5MJ6OLcqTJhbENyoFhrfhlI4A8S7awD8xQeHlrjhN6o1LJttJ6Q/WfGj6T0BRAeUgt4QPgxJO1GjqTSbF@httGoEJE6r6Hfed51zXHPgk@BpmE@6PDS/SHl2tUUT2@mSKjmgt6q4FSbsKNNxuZZqt53uylmpfxNOZOVvUaqKjAPyeJkTxwnekYZMdGriIBe002spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsqAgPZm8U0qmdE7rRNyAPpVoNuNAUp86je7QJXiztJZMhoQCPPomKDqWlYjL5yUov5NsJVNxyJuMp2FmqMXjQBfa8/So0rgowTvRQ3MGpISBCbNsdFuDeDTtj@Fw/dwYD@duNEG48AeCPi7iL47M4MkinEiijPotzx@VKZcWGwLRm6cD@RrXD1FkG8/5BCNwTJvK0gGtYOo/lfojZ6Irn8igt8mRGTu@EVckCSZjiuGQqNpPTA@HsG4bztSLLnauXIPF0iH0eDgFZhmckktDrzLHgtEdOiy@eQ@gs3DLCRk/7p5JfA8uANDryvBDJoqCEe7XgIBD55pM4It0IowWhlRCgrOeYHsgXxi/kcPSqpSHZbAgc2A7riEBSSCHQIe46GigUA@2xg9o8e3a9OPH0qyKU5lpAEd8aDk60Zaz68iW1HgUyW8PMMuR0RMs4B99YI8ybwvX6ClbAm0UO@4QZgioDXJiLWytkR@hON64J09mkFVI4JwfjeQKJsi9Z6ynaVqhm@9XgjjsFUDsITQSKsY2aNlBlKRCZNJv5H2@MhUsEzw9fLDPl29ovscZHpfy2iOnNwXR1lfdjgx7kGb70J9M2xmZQIYg/9sT68hxJnyhATzrFoe43m6OppZOy05XV4ZuzNd1Oo5Fq1E3ZV2kn7qebul8HSyI3f3kCagbL46f1@RKJJGin45uLBuXQlcXy@l5EN32pC3fYIfK4x1T3MyLOG8Fh0@RzfgRBYyY@kdPoY2C8CKGB0MKt3H88BKGj/DYKYjr/kIGecNAP2GZEuJRVDx35weeq5lLDF@rBobpVErHZdcFtueqRuGnk35/KThLwScSsiZrEZyjYH4kdUlNjaKU54nwfOpSmiigAqUJj6muTVekdPyAjRxubj4Jz0EMDSvY3TwCiQV38GDSt1CuAr0JtQR@lNQAIX@MGzXEunH7j3VBDvauSbEw2MYSTy3ENmgAweSmoEgjbCrMX36v0hCyHX/b1ONs1XHTfGVnu8432lGtc7lGqfCNgc02gNiuV4Mzf@uSYUnxeJiMoBJukIOqSWcLrlU1PCni0Xq/QFmqgqeARjPTMlJzVtxvXcQVj8jQZ2KzObuT0T4D1QgPbW7eVQZGlY5ZraFXNYiJ@zJsZ84kkPgwFV877w6Bz7DUbJmU0D5Tu@9YPYlv1EGHYVzFwwbyz0mEh0n9M8OG6QbnSOkgL8@K/DVyBPUa3CtNWr@eIHJoNQQEw@ecXZykTy9YA6a8U9kbW@akxS7lidMe@oe17KvHW7kM6rr63BP8YzY1tnv00SeNTItDEEY6br6VeCvOglPSIDiDoITH2cGFh4Um5oQkAToMYWJ9VRmQmtE@DaAPMHgBVRYW5NcIUb8wLhZ16RugLCcMxNybj9LMSF7KfUufTAyb9zm@A7qe3Hyryi@mRsXv@PseFZahzSGQTE2MAxSr7Pnxg/2jIxl6rpeI7@MmUgWGo94dgoCyrtIBJaOVr7A7vTi7g3mSuHIgwFAD7aPt54dOXYVOD/oHlI68Y2C4CQhM4v5PF4Jpy40ycgnNJxAe@epOiEYhsISRhDoRsMpK/F/YXNXy8axAj08RJYHcibsVoK2ZlKe2@Ub2YKIhuRWS@MoqzBe1zQRxsU016Z/pG@HuNWhYJDRCDRoNJr0FLgeJRdZqVfkxBEiLCpg7QOqKIjUFHaavqUHT1yAYRBqC4GevvWMvGxmp3EptrgJF59v8c/C8/hG4CGEZtGesLHYzQeP92kDmOPDtSM65X5A6feUlkArb5A6RL3tT8uDMFjEdOuK1fFRr@SAYDDJkJbQahBUJWELMf0vB77MUT5wfdB7MRgGJJDsPia4hydnFBdGQbWqMaAgulfHGuAy0T2BMjx2ozWP/DYWodECj1T/LgmO2KYiBmrW8WYwxXIRXTq9Ip9KpGM3HpUPTPnFoyyl0tTOymkeJMMw9OrGu58RzsHRbShriwNNq67DzRp0@3VYkoJ0Xf0@fAmhN35eFQYjUlSN60PL@ipKXz7EsFeufkKWZFtxMenNLSqlcosT9TsdclxSIgEfTgueKZMCksD9rck5Wg1cecCkG5iNgXFx7WVT96hEotkR3/yiv//zP3@gB/a@3zhAmClz8DB1tmLqxpaT@2sbys6KHbqsblq/RTy1TJ8KQ6zaQXd2FKulW6FgNms4BSBJM/yPc1fBbHPom3kBqvKGbccz5pmTwXF3Iqn09G1hmd13aK0fCeFG0AwWKXY@IwIUg06BMxLp4IxgzvgsUUbGRjd2OVHBui1Fn5u0@nE6m/A6C662NaI7xd9PY9FNm8npHNRR@eP6GJnf1k2nPkcYng1BOLaxIu6g9bUNLIA74O9JtdK6uPq8gP4wePNclW0xtyhk9busVnj31xlKHtPAe99FAGN1Qgmvx@7okpv8OYehYTzXTotsH9kQfOnQU/0CGgsddpQjRzCtktvTOHGWQ4ZfvZeHhBuA4tW4qlcmu2d0ej9fnR02S8pfLq3PP5C6nx6o1AoUfqZX4KhpV2D9ke0urwnRljnRL0noR51pmvupsxLWk4bYq5cH3P@glkBs7OU5I3amluwvXDV18gUewjbBuRdqfNp6ZXQfEgTFTi7KqBVNHZMIglhmczlsUhCea6RY5gWGuImPwRosUulazAKc7wVOra/rUBzA0floUz@RGOonsrKNU1znD31rxYQiqKb@vntHersTqA5iTZHUtHebxtdPB0uIgLj7e0lHPTM@g22rCnqxEdNK1VoYvD4Fg2S@6jHdbt/ZMy/HYc7rfRKCBC1Tg99UdOkpLU7clWgyPum/gQcExi0WD6tbAsQqlgaLDbW2rT90@8n3/@aEcLuRQqnoLhwrEH8dW/edavn6iuCe3NRC9M@niEduI84YpdhWb8vde1tcOFAPcuFtds4eZEuWUFb7Ut6Zg3HI50@fB8@eYOtaRNpg6xnMSp0G6wwzlEjgmLhexf57ScjeX1vswpnQNbPG2SkQa98QyYLKi@7UmZVpG/ZI51Ezmw1lU35oaU2OlonHYeW3g2/03KBkfjlTGr8amv1KPmwP4dkyY6q2vGX4Q1jhPo@9GZqJbZte4XZRZZmpjkL7HqDo/A8czdFzPMbCn46VWXdLO7KObSTYcB0Pa6S1hhzFflg@VbpGUluRzz6DfjRoT1/DwjFotn8lkfAEmsuOy5LlJk8qGeV@b/L5UMIUsSl6kxV02N@JcXQaRJXoKci0L0tYp9pS4XFZs0zYmc7x/IDftOI71ZVoKmCq@s@yAtirRad@bWuyauOO/x8IWSxceLnh0@usWLfhs4@uWQB9Umm9q9OiW0Ae1poSbniPckFr23rx8E9lguq0UfL8W14T4@V9rvSzpr4aockku3jjquITqdAxL549ZIXcTvLKcvRHeMtPwN2txc5dv6S624mNXmNJ4DsQye6ClDI2RQd4bpHy9h5Y6/MfaRDMHf@uiZ4bRVWb7RnddgrEJfMHG@9IeckRYmjg26FcTPGqIeoqFh1n90HUcONj1W0nkg5E@MLjpmJs45WLBAk/TcLVu4Vy9dFHhJ2i6kG1hE2R9l4BBdWLMveC5EuCTeRfadTq6fbntyuDv4hroB4z2dador0@x9tAZ2kNjyI@uh751gwP644Sb@rkJdcB6MMTTdOPx0in7KD0tx7I@hJ7IGjmjdJz@Spz28f1bfHnsS8HlL/v7j1sX7/QJ5x3oWDtqhsYU5iXPmThjQyLfuqQWLvTw@zoeGmxS/7wrSDfq@UCR4Pnzwr9VtxzozmQ8pkd7bE09ulFWiV6bvk1u6vOjKXQu03EH8ltn1JH9QNk/t0Jb4KtZTMecdIf43jrv2cbA6XSH5m1I@7YylGDJh3s/SHdFyphMeoDBsmUCed25jP2lFo1/jo@DdY3urx7xaS103CCvrFqhozfDpbF@0vX4aii6WAUXhCOjkb8/XqE38CtvpuZkATRylilc3uXbEuhYh7t/emKtZEWvaSzYsH@qYm0vJSEdBXLJyIDAo64rdvmcW2SIZbP8tg6haC0Jo8i5lC9Dbv/sD60OmpF1Wwhf6l9Lh5ZWTnL2cDrwrjNMvlzfAxENb@uXLeg4dWTJGuYs3fYf68isWQq@ZwnPNshcU@PGPZX8jZsqlE61JN0x4dGGBzTddO0ammWOPX5nUn/tVpx/lgl08av7hZw289XKtN8wPaPPt0DQdZuIOHJcPIkMMojUxZ10XEFHZs4FL864bGcATF2y2CJxkHad2LLymNDq5g/nTOmzp8ZAx7PWj80JHtZc0Suoy646XnQr7K9Pdc/8@hRqtq6zodEIvg3pRq0LoG8FvCf6wOw@WmqIEEmfwP5JT/5Y6v4YdL0tzoamhyeaQscNC1PY5Xgnxl7XBr1hRcqr6/ahvYzFAOJvYq5MvWpt3RnP8YW1ObluWlY3J7TK6j/XqY7rDoHdiMTZdDSeev5jNQ50Ziq6Cj06oXDvzATg0htgrWyoW5PVK9WRJVeQwvxJceFcJ41/blrOgH1eyjAQ2kAIQ@F8Rce5D9PzMzyQ49oreiKV/YHbnrjQIbm8Ym@gbQ18r8I2Jzev5kwmeDgneGJl@MyBbygoj/Eu3/uyEKTj1RR5fLusv3g7@pb5HXrec2fqdg10hiZPomqBX6qxF5w@xjc6HDTZchbV0rqOBcMLHNbKIdN17OlEcqf2jbNC4cZZoYIGryLdgCW@vv/kRTLaG@i09m1SaGASbeFae2DgSiczbRDE1vPR5dSBLvGAm2o6oqPCt@TZRXtSXWLXD5xV@s6zOUwgH6wwAfOfjh4YXdw2vLXsp84Tx3ZgNhoDoxwdGdzswNJBj9UZMdtjfLEe6NO7tZjnBHbNJMSlDX1sdKB9rYXrQ@YiDviBPtHXTEW0Nkj6X@i6ta@YVsdwX9OiX8S9TqVdRuiRMSPdYn2H4WNQmnS7XCTG9bilMbK0Y@ONHcfmd@K2GXioT27mKjAV0O3DN8plPIi/tC6wUj9brurhKT8lYvS4XYx1dXWNjmPx@w1nkmyTnwnQXdPwlMdoZoHCCjkmgfTl3chDijfykIVqBJLsqe7RJv1qVWMBUp19iSNAQ93tOrgT5jtuOJ0TsY1wC5sOz/bzgwMdIPwMOJbenfr2Sm9Dyxp1RnRbqzBEWvPI6OBbQR0yKDLRZ9cbk68M@dYUIie6QhsEAbvCQV1giWegjSRvn7aW9KhlqppjuhGnXrtdTod1JNs0um91XDVziF6LtemleKiz8pSca9aqI8OIVpEVnV62XzmSlo@ugUBjGdJk6ILOr0xuWt4OLL2s2A@ZjgzcZF7ehVkrujrekCrrrN5PD5mra0i@uUHgJaHpQS4fSrtrJU8ED/@H9z9WYBJuF3KB9RNgXbfv4APyU9f2Hx/SA5853qRvzg4Bb3wLYB07wWrlIQs8@MhA19a6SkDr2VOLrz4MIueuRj1SxyQyBi1JFrHriSEZ9qlEtuhm12vk8Je@lF00IDwxepJvigF3GqTHwftfYTL/uWIDNcob8bCnqnDCzgo5//jnKuKeBZwB5C1nIo09eipj79nB48NjeeypK@en3SG@HXFNjluy7aCVMpElqde6G9nv5MfReqY3Ue4/V6W9xwcyJlhDb76jIcEDd@aWHmvXPQNDsoq@VgvCWGOyWkB8dPzkcWrxiiZL7A1dZ2Qko9F7z5@n8U2Tj5@vjI7mfgijo@/M1mY/2FfV5Iru@8Km3cF13HNFSesgHRugjUJnfMRNw9wqXHWdsdE7no@NT2DyRA7ufWDxhbWVfKqfmgMchay8llA0UFlZLuSSkZPZoGwbbvhc154n5hi5ZZceCn@sPY6CkkNWcbOrpYebdvyvSjEs459E@HKZ1Mz13ho1Zazo3t8XMVVV19H5ud6HdmX5tY21nGDV/rDlnH7AVrLhKy9SGCRNoFdJ5q3nyIvSCFi3gjdcnvcDwdlZewzmJgBhcGHlgD8z7LluS7SXdZN4UYHceKjtxiSfGx@wIRWe8DlFe@kr9/jCI/Us0SVn8paCj91Ilr29@we3ZTjyaXlzqo@evmDPdA/toNycMIqx8QEYLySj1xKuW6ERvrXbqT0XQGk3whuMV4/nCnuuuz3Hns9u34Sjd1Bxaif7xiEs9FEiwzJn5qq5qsvXtZ6tPmZ0W9n8JQ5nviQHR@3j@IDef/ufqWomQ9aP8KlmuPeWlgkGOEugS5@jSb1o1PFByBq6KLfIEJBcqY0@NmZ4HIWvBq9S6lfOb4Ub5r5icv10clNc6Ya43A3lXYvDQJaVM@oNAPM3xLG8HEY/dqyzoSPv6a7hrTh/vBKhmypSvqEi5Qh39g2208ai714v4uOrC/5jZW89NiZubjx0OmZuZR12@2jnkj1Be@3X4/3jFLpLx1sGjv/KB/evLu9saqws6In@dnUEcZqTlVHABI3hlF6JuB69vEHaAZnXsAcmN/HI7juTffLdoJiFbzyvPotgjh9Mx@sxBt6IX8W4ys6XEn4KOrNz5rH7@GrcQkxfofvj@bjV4etkWhYuDKKl00fHu0HvOnyuaJESF1h89mwpGF8enRw@j4S5xmy2TumVZut0yJUxi1KfHueWit2uvzxdQaz17xuBuAH8OHyulYM4s/v4@XWWgOrbcDKygpiPdXuxYrrUYD1nQm8arox8Np/RMcqVLT3kp9hWxbndFcFLij1MyKYJZXtKu43mmNrtdb3y2PiM9h5ADGITLpZwoL7hJWOWGwYYUpa1A9U5WQg/S@g@Hw9Ne7YyarQuD50iTbz2Vg@DXfbccs7Y49Cq0Dr2oK0Grp8a9jrmtOplRamcvVkKy14Rqda1C/@Aiv9Y1yT31wlqV3gGHoi4iZtg/qOu8jDwfKIlb03/8fMg@e1p9ywH1@975nR0e2ICm0rdntC9gf1dBWjengy/N3IydFz79qRBd6pU7hsfiMTGB6cczbvOB@DQ6fdvT7TvObcnejK1JibqLKuTPnWmFloQWBW37w5Whte3682mXJHXRaJBd2/oJtfH47lIZ@qBDmSGzDPMKL02J0uBQZ@JhqF9ecOWbSd5Be7HDvsaWpJfQYq3H9hGHz9cl255w2aKW/z0RvDCue5Q73ievXWQvzUH5PmQQWeboxvTLkz@HbiOzX3JddPjwvzfipIe6daq8cVfsAf@HP0@hJf2zWtxgxTcDIAnBx/xSCRsaMbk8hfTojYN0Ip6YhOtCG@S/QJIe3HBNnybARAhBlYIfCsJaGzUtKcGmjng31Ga1DahmFpNzZfZDn6irMLUDJWJX14sc5uOQWENtnnuWwCoVNRLtlFjYkVkvg2G0EQ7NzMOgNFAMlSKSScq25xAzGZgP4DRF3PYBaNlT6mLdmjBJytRSypV38IC4LR5/uzg2f7z493jF88bmdalb4EhqIVtQ2mBnZc72Z4IlffpBuoU/@gAWf6woDj6mg8ul3pBvRh@IWy5arWlqi0qJe5gns1z21YUMkKhSJeAnyTy0igWhQII4rCDGlMD@fZHKtweBJm1gDbioEUqExqtwjKrCh7roBps2n781Q/qUSx@dLGCn13Egn078dATB47T80v0DHb7FZT4cPfg8YujfRYguOg1Z2ZvMqyV8/wzAtwwDrRT36RTuTUW97PEoa1qtfjDOBAmLsdZhcyGkAl/6OiQLKAOGhzxc2@xxCbBBwrGw0ZR/vM3lMu4jC@YJCFtPEAqDsVCn6eOsrGxwY6hk7AHRwef7B8xxH//AQUjiRAEO0abBX/24x7/CE5gUyz44KQ7IjmebDIJUbslgTGPhb0RpDmN3fH6z07SR2fIqkf4tZvwc12CQB9Dgn57RhZJr5iKTJL1Nv6ZTN@SZ1AQdaHgwxm4l4lWOV2PnZqeiTZFEIc@Gslc7ux4/JFs08psF7@piV/u1OmLTID61J5wQ3S@OaoY9DQ55DlptknI8u83iZGE8e0N6OwdA1Q85tkmTDKTCnsNPRH3Cyvc5owk1ePXsgSgK@SSUC2IJLxmVdNTmq7y/tf@iTKoMnBPwP0d3z3L3Affr/i@Prh/lbtfKtjRrlvhXOASRQiN9/o14IiE9EfaRz4lanM7PwvCobHQgLEycwTNdEpUx@S8BH6XgB8v4CQan0CjQXeDFvPt@/DyDLeVQOvBFUXBLoXLDjLNlcaMH3W@YkW4kC/kVAWQlE4DgPTZjwHacOAAk8kKDBPh1BzXXoEqu729zURcezRqhSpvWWXTfpkVX4WIbkJa4WyIyDUY5IEsixwQV/ezweyTUpOYFblXXI0j4@o5MC1RPE5f6Ld9QogsAcTiNDLwOxIz/OrsBCRy3xp2B7/TGvkk1KYPSFJhTiJXUhR8yzhPnQl0Hxiki4@@ccs4eNSfT4Fo49Xj32ImI9TYH@XrI2th0CH49pQ/1mTkARxUNnN1No22rfgpgniOICriqu7beMmak6bdUnjfZNBNf7iiM9vg/mVlsKbP8nrvXrf/m7hqvReJxe49tx1cZH0IlWEJTdGyilpILqqUy62skl8jvxioDhoZu4DigE0By@ga5mtn7O3u7R98fPjs@TUbt5QyfjUZ8P36dqopyelGK3TEo9VabpL7D5XnT@4/DBpigXQhwo2B8fs1UW@qyWLvBEEu3sW7WrVVGF6t3XqMP@XWOq7im9VuQo0yXcNDzXyJcul9GOkhvdV6tXCttIpa@fxNKC3gKRHQe9wkwTVUE8nzy0YLNBw7Fr/eE1YMhJcxeQsHAbia3tamgp39euWwYuFX0o/x25NedCxmV49FcTOLJhTRIsrEOVkYmfQDIhGR@gbFAIsUZCVIunb0HXIhfWEKVeNfcee2F6OW5SIIFzI3UTwC6jj4IDxykYUhZ9@G8RC0D8vsCIFFP27LODC5Gpox5tb4EknB/yIRLzjhfyJ@VpnJdPg1kURuR7DS7CazyAG8pAADGqW7Z1PQgp45Y/6FCjrk9MAIXEcOsN8HU74oarCPpyNI16fHkUEbzsC5JcgMlIyHqHJZCriEbxV5lkK701BeA20j@xWXR718YpaUh8asZw6AtyeSaeBod1S1xULLyVhpspRsx0Vqs0Ur3DgUP0JDE1Gyfynz2bMFAnpDl027Z8wS8bN4stKC8jE8fvbpaTwprupLZMbbt2vdu2rPO0S/qN7MSfSJPzoDY9mruEW5fJ1LQNhVwNyuZPB5vHJZHnoCfe60hpL784n7GJwgRiT6I33MElOb2@SUGXkTzYSdJmOFUp3b@7VZKkUKFTwoQmaUs08uPn8ndHvOEkoNv4gLoZ7dw8dbc8waqiy3wE2FJNkmfrZyDyQutFKbFEAJhiwVAlvDLgRqBmDEB4nMOzjkwXhICw@ybLoimr7iR/tyDtKEas3qd1nkM6TLkqNYLlf8Bl3mimUGve86O5QVAHuNzwVyPVDXN9cFNAP1VxZiC0Z@nePFqNwYR@SRb@cL0IlFbHQH5r8YwFpY0O4OXfwl9m0YKyAfVCovjh@2S0lFZKG9sIFr9nDfmH/pIlTx/G@TwTBVlpLGq1yj@wizoWXWNjdIhgZCH9KAEa@w1FiUDL5160BZ9hZ9U1Vv7PV@Rr8VIGUOJwD/vep2AA6t6QYLyiviVjP7n/0shsJGYlNVT9ruaSqez1ThplbzLM/ubDYlabORqd3b1EGLmryZNUEnV7ZyD06NYb93MFCaosiyLKcoW@fn5/GHW8/Ml3lWkHqmVngzm19mC9k3s8usWnpzMlYLDfnNrCWWaumTFnv27LN37XdJcXY6fyM2E1ps7/BCVHOo8scqZXa@U8jGTsqgfkK5jJ2wt3Cd9Bn@k/ttL@LW0d3pgwobF1ms2QSKq2JRVJRGvAX/pO6/gosr/o26XJd3Wu/eJRu6PpnNmWmaY6/Xg58zBAlSSz5noC/fBU7PMyisSU/SoPAazfrX1xPyjM12jcFguq/XNXzlXr7Xrs7N6cPJk88/Da4XeL09imR7638nO5VKSFJjxTpFpa3nY/jF7T/7ycZl@vxZe/vPvjlSjA18HOLjO5dP0P1czd/Z2Lhz/34ul9Y0jbufff7sF3d3d3MP0vlnjfxOTspsbP/pn2xsaNq2pmy0PE9txRsnJ5@JWiYnyn/2o3j72bOve149@39@411dxVsRbqesCHwCrixTwYn3EvxUlLE@9Iq9jUEvV2Nz@mvHgvDzDabWd4r/5XuHb2KTWF1TPnXhOYm9iRVKMe4EB/iyge80Vo9tY7LCZWyu1Go1cBb/y7@F/PWPAQ7GzLfhVs8HsArzWF2qUZaLWL0ADlXToNz/@xvfiGDI2USNxLjguscacIm5oibutODaomtbQDusUkZRgnT2ZDgxHKaW7qp30WOCBx62gR@0MCbNmFrKMXZ4j7GjRiqVasltCS75JS0SKaqqNVX1LrAD6c5WrSZtMW5pNpvN30Vr@Ula0ho4MGMadz/9h7hiqwKrPze4IyFW2Lj36kG9DnXK1rNb9RRd/kCiMVUsiY5zT2Rp9ioOKkij9eox4@ax62KmpInpdPpem/wzpJU0C3sSXvwei4UhOGTZ1bClLJDED419@XSxfbz@/H/78@//@ffo7/v0@w9oqNbumX1lCxKdwpCow3WvUunW62LdFc@b6K9DP8pUSpWS0r5sJraAA7WOmJr56CKez8afI/enq5mEMUXpqdi6Xzz667FFcJ2H1KNhfgRPTAHw9CnFYstUI3dINcaupIOp1T/SLzVO6y0JBaKa1FAL@ZbEc9WDq8wa96CZRK1YFlt1La8dsnvtGb/YcNNjTgw0w0JARx/f@qJu9TBm4atHg2L1IFt9kebLpgvxFWKNhtIyaEIIwti9jcpGqVKoaEq7vv6Crhn1UlLDMJ55sdNYeHHKxhYEjYVd82pY0BShhwU9mH2ZdNBYKxa7tSsXo1bKFlSx6ru0NhOr0EO0rKQN2mJGFcPRhuv7cG3AH/3DFXrxvkEhfjAluX5tsIq6pWWV/J3Cvobz6y1XFHkB5gnW7XQ6b7sdkDp0vaN3dXWiT/WZPtcnnWln1pl0p10YNjwD9DX@72advFNyAq8sxbJ5dTN2F2YdTJwtZ7PFXLZQyBbK2WI@WyxmixmtlM9q5Wwhly1r2QKEaNliQStBSClbVLMlnAqypbJWymWLWSH2rrHBjjgva7FUcDVTt14vZLntO8nh4E@SnFlMiP0DXHVVU9kWzHIZuIFoR07QvPFPVQUWA3HtvPVuq/FuC4Z5PbVNLLZVl3ws4SG377VS0uVlA9zVqv@/XQ@dVbq4CyrXukyltl/WQYZ5WW@kAORLH6QsMQIqt@utbYoJC/NL86O3WyAFSantxnbN2aOfTMNMiueceMG51wLA20vI3ruXksF1DwDUN2FUJ1OpTUnawBm24c84kLhVTwW1QhwSIHOcn/@cP1AXgRdcbl/WLxvbl5fb2/C/TfdL/wmhl9vX/umxuNakWcS3kEE1G0q9qTR9ltMCv6zUMURWmuCowxPSNbJaqdVAB1xy67/Nfzm9uIchiHJLBqyF2BbbiqHx1WxsS4i9ev/F/4K/5vsvfh@lTgZ/RkWInSNzULZQZy1z1RVuzH5isyf8ssGNv8CLIRjwpI6BNr/ZuK2lKK9kVuE7Bwm1VEjKOI23nX4b7bnI7BUkXWKpyDeZqJUKYjulzjUW2xYLRWKav3Dtisfj/@iVVi7G@XIPGiR55XnekwiWCzwhcVXLqJJ6Ueff3OCfR/qFVdc/@oV1lxC7KDOjAvRJME4YIQb9KKYokgTTXn17hG@s4IaLhLrtae0z6cWuhIsx@oS207p8oaF2sF8rl@t8r2jzGY2arQdbcFfhf38DqsGafUjb7Ne6IxCjm/1sXmviBxpiUucN/j1@i3/suIt/R2/wjx2/xb@jCf6xJx38O36Df7sd/Dse4d/9N/j35C3@vRjgX/Mr2axaFTfPiTIptaxebs5EolAVZql68ysTd16hr42J2o4GyqO/XpXI5srJWPMrxqxrjCcVf2ER3x8yupOqXitXOzXNT@offsYY2fSCz7n764gVjSVxxTNbzjuuhCf14AYBqWxZddz4T7/7zW/Ga7W4FKcPReUgTOpgog4lAi/kzHFM8AO8gB@0t@fFq/fiX2nQWkK@3GpgZAsihFiNbaqbasbKdDNqR@2Aw2QZl2WGmaHaU0nnyhgsM8/MWWbkqD1wGfCXAZeZ6bPMgGXsjA3JIBZck3Zmgq4@PAbw1wdALvyZeAi8o2a6DAqyUPakb@KqbcyZuWg3hQaLM/GVAUqzrMoZuWC28DNeDfHVq6ay1dLKJSZjv5bbjVfNeEtsivhpB62cY525sdF8JYKMkRF5/8cQFvM80MSrMaXZVDjhgVzUkpeX7fb@0wfttoIzYfOJc7j4PzwcRb03/o8OnSeHzsiB/8PDQxi9Rj11LwVzxL17NZgz/MdOrF7daVZo5glmn5iyvdOsZyV0F1IwoWgYlvqS1wIiPOsbTSF@BprQGShR1QSoUmfV02r1jByfci842ujGwPD/zHf4T4JQDRWxM7hOCSz50Hn2aTN0cYfy6RkEfcpAgQz/QVONev8r/Jv/bf0/ecGSLNFoJRPnl9sJupL4l0yeX55f@vd6MpHwPYlt@MMA8GOW88s6OinRObgaiWQreXnJw@CeSG5zgHUoZrtOeRfpYGaKhUVSsfyW@K/7hKL9qxmvggDPFwnyGRpHMbHK9MUBoWZzlskkgc/5X63B7W79gk5hJKv0ydLNTkNt/emP6MtEO0lKlM9Vq@oW4x4tp1WrucBXLFWrpcCzmUiUr1/1zI5aAEUql0smq1Xw7ARgM@CFvA32LsVqrAn31t27vJCSdnERwMzmCqkMHsyqVoOS8lCs4eldn@mfHxzSR32A1eRj@DUtzkoSGfokGE4EcbEi3r2b6Bn4pkFvZzd5965WzlxchCHjMQSpS0Htds90220Mz15ciG2RDvSU8@DPlC4u1Ew5pcaTjpt4it8rhaISksruaHUqtQxMXssVIdpHIL@9XcjV64UchBRK8SQeDuAsHvCNi/GqGDunOqilIueAYhWDowedYCx7ONeeX8aoQVkun0wAI02CGHoZwz8XeS6f6/L5JFDmUuQp1XKZJ02yXCFRSpX9v9pGktVBzuJ/KCxmU7mt4tY9ELvxz5utupAnV8@NmnpZOzcquD1wWe36H59HwzjG3bvZMpColKk2hXb7we7xbrtdg7kMZTW4YSBxdwHtBbnxSvUetatayjNoQB4oxWFKYCWgsqJt5dUSUkUw@2joCmggcD1vg20IGj3xJpQ5qTYgEFQoKK0HF@uxDhvgxQaodjKTWXQxi/F4une7YSKHX35s6KW8pJkGIUZ4Cf6wy/I@CbP2s8e7e/vHaW1bYjHt4e5eWnv@4n5MRW9@4afoLPqP9ncfHL6ADM8e7@8@3//o4JP9F88g3GNniyvg8v598Yy6VvjP2KfCa/etbhi6MTWM9tl0evaGvTbNtgmtZ02hUs7AZZ7RhrqM9UW9qvDrmp7@@rXujuli73/47fc//O/e/8533//Ot9//zvd/@sX3vw2/H8Pvu/z53X9TzuP9p1/8s999/9u/A4H/AX5/BL@f/PSL3/gG/5H/j@H3nyJhf@z/Iun4TwBYv/LTL773o59@8as/gN@/9H8/uP77tZ@s/n3/W@t/mO97v3tzmu/@W/j9HocVpP3ub/MwfF5L/9s83a/@4P2/@Hf8/0/9P3T@zvt/8cd48z3/9Ad/@p/ef/Pfa1rpT//1@2997/23vvn@W995/61/rL3/jX@tZqK3333//T/4qz/8vb/6w/@R/n9M99/7kP/3P/inf/G//sX//hd/6P9@Ar9/B66f/MW/h6Hyt3/wQ/z/3h/87R/9EP//53/1t3/w63/7K/8TOX6TO/6ff/lv@P2vf@0//s1vfeevfvKNv/n1n/zNb/7BX/0fv/p//cZ//Ov//vf/@p98EwN/8yd/9Ue/8pff/PZffuuf/@U3v1hz//aN9y8@IPyLf4CQD8fzQ@B8SL2@bMgXPxc@fx9qLEqBfgK9@5ff/8YvQQf/F4y9//aP8R1S@K35/7GmUpofc9//Bxza9TpjTAZc8Pv199/@LpLofwASwX9Ir@@EnqUY7vnOwgNk/a0VmX75p1/88x@RL2ZU6rTfhJN1SSultkCh2SqX/Qnb34qCLL@0DC0E4Jf0HeRQS3HfQd72/offeP@jf/z@h7/5/oe/grO1lCund9OSess@HiTMf0A6TFj4kHSY8DMov52iZT0p9Rn4Nj7Ll7K2bVc/@@wzoX2h4MvK9y7YZ/DHPgsuxqPwZWY/KojDcHy7mUF449WrFm7@RsIUlQNXNP70o/BsPpQkaXdSO4qq8SjjQtnkuVgVArKlbDOCutLvb1Xgj8GtUtk6T0s7TRD6KOulYARVUn2oGwpT9XR2K6tDQiXH07GKfS@TSxW3dB1U4BTCTZHMsxXIYPksm6X8Imds5q96zzDRbIucM1oG52vhcBfwRv9Fxkosy5jN/6sCS9HqON@jSS2c5PDz@UVwp5CHYlKzcPuNhELGpbItHkI761RursywBrNZagbaNjighBRE3Qe5v1ZLYcYaRxG8vDL1EiNUUqka1Btz8zzpdglBzO4TFMhZSx2x9lZtxjOmEF49IEdKwKAjUdXEVKn2AAqszR4whIXACeyrV7V6qTarI7h3nDqpWeo@4YTAaqlZ/R34awQT8gmxB@8AlVItlaqXsECsJG@edJs3Up4qR3VPsZTfBvDEFyR27jF2R1RLIt9W2UCC8dR4Ty1SY0JIDvHN1JZfHfoPnPTbIoJvUFF@KYzH75BMvMPFZEwAcCVJlmUGPzyxsMPuQfSMg0pRsfBIcQgp6hHUA8IAhgtRKSFF7ZsiD5Qfq2196QuBYWU2NzeFWF3MiocykU5RmHtSobdF8AAl6jEVJhbKIgYb9OpMgAvkr1L5m3HciowzDpjdSfHfvXtb7A5Uk56LMIFJqayTc2IcynYqJWoAv@6khJeg/wjQTwnQhSDParT1mRLSacbkWgzj2OHhoY8EBbysCSno5lpWRT9uwE2n0xjkkOW0nE77T5meFCD7Dpli/ae8icQ9c82JwTQtVwU1rcowiEV1KhV0bQx89@4dtAqdSKscgJbL/MNpWq5EkRDAbUVZ1jx4x0rLlQW@BMDUQo6xBC0nw5Vk@DJRAjpSUuBvMnA0gisR10qlOKUE@suJreC0YkFFDsDf2qJXh1m@uOQFbKJeXBbki8@xOtYsuLiyWsong8i9Q7Z3@OTJ/tPjcavFBPxw7HRitMeu0zU8L4Fxu08f8JdetHIhGWs0kCrHFQ05krBfyWBHTR08ODp4XmGcSn6bJageVdq69ulSVoXYePzpdsw/3CXi1z8d8TneKwtSJLQycMtkrC7EugaqQHgmAVXzKqsKT7zBfWfGEpm0KKbVAqqgSdyBBTx@0ZkytE3NDVnBIMRXYeTtbaKAUD@XaF8HndC8BaFe949FMlWoP98/hgzHh0zVMrJQ/4zNZCxQuhTqVs0y7MFkuInnC8VmRozUabORSeOfls3CXc0V0mq@2NrYsM4lLLNJrXyOB0UvwXsuYTW@ChcTviqwr0IQXFAGnv5k/gr5wWHVP/@IViAT/BCkqOZhXCYFXOXn4IRx9KrCcFjeJRNiG59/PmH1Omj@0sFDIQbsZciCI4CS2ZOHMjVzb@oaFDtgrGd@YuJnXeWe6Y0tfQ5jDagRu7y87AOkg4dMq2vk5Tl6eL/sUkgH3JczXYjZlUrtnZorCke7lcq7rKYJECBsKXjGcAM6AB3V2FL4X9WDQrLZkgKsTRVFeGSzWYG6r1AxBEbHcd5lajWJ98FsTqXTOAJ@KUif1Rb7637a2Z1F2myGp8UYiGCDicsyQVyRx/m@gkA@IBoeQKTv0lf90Zy5ezeLyyvZXCZcR6Eas0tom81sLosUxxe8WrFc0d9BEkWxFRMsY8J6NXDHmnDjS4WaGhMZ@pDLZEsZIdaINYT/v1/@Jtn2uJ7NqNvKGJw6OHPbig7ODjjz20oHnCY4y9uKCc5pPatmtpVpXWDCNjcgzdA@VU2cGDO0V8/DxLpnWH0Z3/uqiVSAJm77H2SoBxnrvVrP6U7xyE21J5u2bbhoTYJnyOXEqmOjadNasDUFTCp5LgxqZ2TzQjBqAxmtZbm2bgk9ueP05rI3mVv4BpXluLU4CLbxIGIB3QCJB5fzdrLZXKXBWvLYGe8IWr6YaqgZmKrwp5bSWnrD2CkWKz25axm6u5Ov5EvpHr6c5e8c7uQzlYH82ZPHjyaT8ZFBb2zt5MqQAe1LoiW4nVIln281GqKYalAxrUamJXO@Jm1sADMw9J4ET9xX9CSt1ILMPdOt1eLxnayqSWolmyldCgvCIc2xhnUBs6awZmmk@7nPOiq2YwOXqqT1tHlOVKj0@/3LrfPUwiPo5xL3AX0uJT3dOQ@9VSmSrsKmaclcREKI3gdyn/tbphVRy5fEaqO68BcLYrV1KdwbGT1Txxe1mpnz67kKwM051BgU1GTCZcV1nEmlY/Qd11gkzKqFICFH6HqCnHgZFtfMYInn14srRBLNzq9DyeXFyzBXgJZweQl058QGsvvWwet0oLmhlnOtfeBd0H22A8PhmCz28qUQ2zr6JFuvQ1Of54paLp/La9lCIV/UYKIq5wqg3mXUTCGT1zSAkiuXysVL6NeK8i5G3wVle@dBf6/Ql1ESeoWb9m20WPLdU9M6L2UljkciWb28jL0TYneOPtFgZl17JWC2/kST6rVsvgyuLLq0LCDMBE2TtKyUVSU1i/@3ODT8//D0GvxreIdcWU04RntfT2G@BRnBZo/RbtDEYccOfjluwO4b3TUp9oY6nTbfcx3P@3ukua/bJzzqgcmNbIdRj3T8fKY3MifDNSlejEdoKsxw/8Eg7I86gCCyQ57gPtxcy3FWJSiyF8/W1PJJ@FkLIAb/rgUkPzr46NFx5Hm8v7v3SCiw@4dPH1x55P1EefZ4/@Fx6C3y2CBrPgTxi/uPH1/1@o/c4Yuj/tRx8Sc8PHyRW9zCIHyZWcjBtZwoDCYg/g29JJGCKAIqX74YOFQBX4G5C2r4Xd@ZLyycGXR@yt/UNr3wlQz@0n5FOA5e39YZctqOwbrcIhyuC5C1Vl9nUItlQRgz2zljxQzrOZalu8zp9zcgcKjjq6gGSsKWhT0Riz5zXKt3ZvaMDeEJvvVaBoWiT0gIjwDIaNolYyMgBaHtb5jVbIY7bR1rarDpmK0NhAcGodM1B0OYg8@cIIHQ0XUGvy97QX4jek1uDpjwMijsWox1PbkA2mMpL4p7ovhIn@hV1yi@zFQqz1yYi3VvYOzPoLuyFzB8dHeeLqWz4kR8yOR27OWWNsCdG8sZo@rijRsg6@/kSo3WTvOvf@vHf/cnvz6oAZ9pZvYyeVx32t558jjnzPWKzUVBpfqOvWT5CjA7EIgZyby@XCyThqSVS/lSOauV0qVyKZdXC/l8WtXSoI0Wy6BfZNSSWijly2q6lCuDXJIrQ2y@XPSlaiUQo5WtCoC1u9a0Z2yTkiUPQZvie63sbUJPspge@qdMNCCPKKACPKEX/bfMGkypTM2wbJEBRJ11Wezhw73Mw4eieB89eFZlLyOKPfTkS5lM8b4oGhSzV0IZS3R4nhLaWBUn3JPJ3AeiTzkA/DyJKA7Rs1/AJURRNNGzt/vwIZbTR4@G@SHZCY/hHivwFCGZjR4Q9gnAmxAaJNvl5eQI0X30YJEY85DH7EGcKH4UoIMxRzwZB/AoqOnurigecM/uLsbsUbXzHNGvoWeXLlF0wQODQRQH4Bi4MAxFsQNOHBKi2AVXd65D2Ahc@AULe6KL4pyTBwkkijNKrXdPRLEdhGMxn/jY5JG6FfKovNb3yFPGP1HUAqQxWTb0ZEUxF3pyULdHjz7Rh5OeMeDX3OXPLtT00aOsbs6m@w87H33UGQw67nx3/6MjjNrbewTyyXzqdgYdP2OnDZcDufYeafrJaH71gloftNsV3VoZ9bV2O6fbV6La87aBGEKuN4CZfw2woFF7D6L2HrXv6av2yglgG7nBCJ4dvO6P4Hlf7/Co4KIoes46HbGK3V9RmgkBNQjc9MbheALc1U6P9K7rVNE/q7FMGoWYeaOQaVUpgo1AE8hULzG@n8C7jutOyfN5Y1bLtGqzWtE/5dZPiM2ZljfF9MZoRy3nKxv6jqrlUrMK2hpx@nEWl9QdllDvbr1liafJHQ20ArG5syOJDbW1o6mlSqH4cmsqiskK3neyxcrbRCaeYQxvyUaxtVPMR3IUiyld0SrFIshmQJMJTPEdXN1pJxJnhn6STCK2tNYAVaC6sjnV06z2E7P0rMbxYvNkdVZTq9xyO8tcA9bDz4RMuxPH5SAHAG62k6ngAYuEqJZLIiCgKIlkMmR6oPoLi6O2n379@OT4@DMSAuv@Msgz10DuVfW9Hz3akw8OAx9@4EN@iLKp48p7yLWWYriQGgQdg1YiP4JpFTS8IAzf6XQdS96nw4kg4AYRgY0x2Te2LR8/WoLzfOic8ZLRJEaVLLbaXYPh90/MHtNrdXDpPZYgrJiePKMJvV2v19q1EVmNgCoGub7G6OMgCzAHHsc9NNRB2c/xPUc/ol3LXFY7tVlsBnDaNSapr0ZO75WW6lZ7@NmT@7X7mLnahmenatQM13VcEfRrsdrfsWtT29P7xjPDRRM0B4ebIF7gy4@JPjOSm6y5j6n3UHe5lOousxeYPZ2OErpU7ySXg3CJLwxA4iS@HlT6nN7HbddE8bLar7HES0j6BvzuJkv05PvJnVwV6HSftZMQlHnVf9VnGivkqqR7JBAWDCWiD9ZbZ8la/Wvw4LBPKhXAxm/oE4CKhQFgs0cRkHpsXla7NYslJDZjSSJSrjqoNTD7Bd62JVFsSVLjoiXUJelToQ7jtTqP6TVv2qEvZrFMR9UyheoMwtRirjqE5tVfzqpubTx1jaoFXn9lkL96rFeBqEA7APP2IvH@l76R3JbyNR5WJVAXKAa05XZtVrXRBi90jFq2BhGpRi6TBq0ebsU0zPlaIa0W0tl0Li0VMRQm/HQ@DYGg9YDIkbASImNiOjPLyGpaNdR0IvPK7L1Kpk8SIMgQ0VgyPXH27emIQQg0FfZN8sITyJPStizQxnoO07cl6qzAMqpYMaD6kI3N9BBBHRm6RTmSSYlltxLWZgLTbB5Px/uNVqWyPxt/HaIS0pudQqqYSb1NJquJjWTNM94I9apQR/ZCtR5vQM/1F02ZNx01oJXBpRa1SqPRwSoWM@lsJgu1M9sXg22xLrbSmY2CCk10yYhtMM43ouuIKPEswsZtlMYtA5pOLWtVQaZFvWxJk8pKfiuf4QuLPKcw9tkbUpIlmmLwmn0iHi9q8XgyXsU9kA3RX8MGnkb8LA7cNX5X3RFBGBMrYlnDBAvWSG9SZwLsQBy7FFBOZDlQds@Fy/PL7brwFeE5vh@7rb3Ev@LLJ7uH@PcVCCqDt/TyyYvDF4cPBabQeVaQO6sbVbnaroJHkuv3hFiFMeCkTd8GmLLB2Jc9KZvarr/kzya@pQFwBbKr32AtOsFmmKjJsU/QvsQOi0MddHfU0LRsq6EVYe4Dbhok1TS1Cli0Y/geiFyHxpidA37bqTq@mvk1Np/rKSlQ/@9W6oPUZkabx07bYqGc5a8Y1tXMCduIF7cYiDMSi52ebNQLW6n4s0o2FX8Qz@Zip4nmZh1P/Ze3tlLaPC5tpXA/V@ltpfql1J3sVvxFqlIapCtqCu8a3CtxJm3E7rXT95JlT6AGYbErqxG7td3B0W5w7G93r17S5v4LpbGXbbFU9BFsbgLBtNTL5dx1mHpf4sp7U8BXCOKx8ziLxS/hT4jdo5dWNf7SKouFr63iNri/OZTNFVgyVk76vmI55iXCnZmvxO/F4rgBUvG8dzHqUME7gV97pUFfjtlOEADqHS69wVybz@MuQUx5NfY@10rZJweH9gP3oSHEmhsXGw7u2bDFGcd39sdfZ2wM5I2zZi02q@X84/hqvS6p2xqa6SuyCkwnfbUgZS7qfMDUKaKgQcz7X/pBbrZdAr@WUcGvafmUVq@rWxpUbPz@i99Hg0vn@5/sPmZxXOn/uz/5kVb8uz/5V3RqL35Jq/9athiDlOhUC8XY@fn4/PwSLh6Xj7Vi1w4rtIA@iqqXi1sy1EYp6eBoKzFORxCgimoy5kkx/2hmIS8lEqqiJbeypUwSYi58g2oJLVMCb7ABRkFiIS8mY/tHZl5T723vQM12sjmtugFtqYYvILPwb9vwyqhMPnl1wRh4uvXeYGBq5FIUVnknbb9j0jZ7h3tP76QN9qpWx8MWKr62HOzNbOFrnLihGa@nlK04A8WL1RuX1ctWijZ3SGl9uWU3r9ChuYFv4CwHbdnwZ2x59GcY5KUAD7yBz9h67YmJraSi9Hri9SW6bYPl69BVtpTFy9VsK9iy4X@S1Ey@/6Xf0LTC3/3Jr120L9qfaaC8lssFVYv97GfbU3vqGb36zwDADWZ2AgWUZFC0h4OOUHFl3N6v6ecKHXIXdOapjUI6Tx@osai4MhBwzIFt9EiNFU5RKKOWbXNLj70EJdtCKxxpEvLJslqyKgiBNMyFeHfQTRMMtoVGqhutpHAufBWjYM5noAhUha8uQEHACGZ5p9v2rKk7pjeYEpRPbaXZXcgCJXwVrWhukPUQf8KQgHMqW9ezcpQ9ohoJcGxkeB7a5IS5TvgqZPEt@VtzNtbR0A2mNG2YoWRMQnhSRK8BZbegbItnaFNogmrPE6QZx45nskHQF74KMgtRwQRRhpnbkKAKbOWrQACoQ8IHbLbYNssm2bmZSlUXBj8v8UUHfKFHD4xsCJgNofXQqEuQuYrpIAgUDPx2NPYLv4VBkowEBkA4DH5coQYqCmYnH0qHZAXng0EBLLI4l6Cqsbt3F1jVamYvyahGCP/EHOOSG7WDvRpXABaod3d6FTHN0JRqNQgNux1QPEXoQq@TuA3VaiQrE9F7KQjw/8GdFnvklaaiiCpWwG8vPiq6QDLIjGTnbdhl2zWmasUkC5HvAu5dQopMHYQ6a3N2R9Y@CyIvAcOfxYIvswHTOo4uY/r99qqVFQYS/RQ/i4W29jgz8K2jcGt6yPwOJkHuMBdUxbQodd90QZuicxSBIc9EVk1itoXhU8KDXkXQcgzfCMgn8UG5MDWDp44GKf1yNsiQVteBBvXGjk0WLMnCFr6OAT0CeJRv/I@jPbXP8DOKfttQ5ihGHhn@w56PGJNFTgdNFVFePJfQcUHrDmiTZsZAZt1Rj2lllqCORkYK7RBckjIRwh0QypHGHcsYAUrPDYPeI/QqijIAQW3aIUuNT0zoV8OHJsxAtqc84ARWzswTUzlGe@aS08fXDbndmxjKdjj8@BEI3yqi5TgnzDJPDL46nViyGuQxUEtAsk4DZRc/IGwFD@No2TSujqhpngp@RXgUubOUjuTdSMyT159ZdSPRxha9oPnGhFaxjFPdjtCXrgvB18e9uRfYHSPrWeCXQ5Zr@BaHanG0JRKa0hJ8C2o1Mt4l467HOCHGxMDyGDqFsWucMtSsBZxjgGl2Axs@OIqhtl@lCYDGHowsNEg6cStoeQowcXuJLgw9n8Hb7A7LagIm5GbhfBNuAAObvrYMHeIgK9bDm/SgYWRa6ke@AqNz1IM4tHnidz/MH/RudJOx2EX3Zhs@OJx0qKwa48Mi8OQjHhwd2J@p6hsQWQAMV2CykRBTADYlJkUOOsx/NTvv7QLxkgq7DinNEIJPaoBCooKOLActTka@dyhAxH3d4x/F8c2Vnp2dyWRDd@qasuHhNwA9x9YtZTwwQSJ2lIkxGvtfWze7yjiAu3BJ/NOf8ng43pmhXFsr353zpyD0vZp/QikR73txnBxP8RN3gxHZ20NDdx51qIcmfR6zm/APTPH@p7XS50H/q2D/k0rxSwTCGIKZpefpbhqApTvdk3T/rFf1I05pQAJwaEUjCETL1m7gGXmByxz3wxTOBPloGNWxTmjvGCCJfBl5UTSvYZByHnh9/9icQSbbOGO7rqvPExSfxNTYgRNzEnvYHKZ9igEnfjDgnJtZNmeNeWsp@yzMDpNaeHLCRWN6wvnNQLnNbYyf8fgZxM94/GxRaFBsY9biIhkGXWJ1sNejDdYgJYKZB2kuuX3qRQxBBnmcqRwEppwvhV3Cr1uj3AG9uQ/asRZ0DOgTYyC4kVAaL5uNZsv2jLOtVkoZQGcXiRDQ4gC60SKanvVCN1LfOrXGjrcUZKPpXZiVfLwxqDv0ewPvK1jHsIGoY3B6mWgtdTDyj3hwgcCvMEBAOQwiUTTYnSTMZDU08k6R0HEa4oLGHLGGj0yLpC8/yg8DcYmTnhM2CqgVAYThYZUATYhhwcjhX3wNuMOnrgNpgrQSfaRyhFb74q04UPLKUOG8pkqNFMFKkgI0gewortauViWIh6ZoXImKVPPSb/8o@htfGv0@jIvV2FOH5RNGVYgOFTyOCSKEP1yIqqxei7QrYKBs6Zbhwsy1z@VTf7aGYraUQM3g5WAVvDNz0h0mIo3fTfL2oddRRVushF1hXqtBFec1Piz5uAhIygkeZvP8bPOgI/j5OQMBGJmV2Qw/2yyabVarccbBZmuynUWQnBGSM56Fp56tQbLlZwPt6SCYXrB5WiCd4nlREeCpfBoFMWgsMk8/NXAj/jVaFMWtC7/MBc@hXuD3IRSxsZ91WytLb0SQjjCtKwCwI14D0OMfj68IVxmeKoW@kEdxUgY8ivv8bsB5BXQwYsFVbnU7EXYy0oFB4BdTNA/A2BVTDUFUafkZ/zL8J6aDwOCnXg/MLKdUlwMz6St//yCBLaRsZIBGpA81k0OGjJrMC9s3VxuVOWJsdwoKDkh1nTOHJVYI2xCuTP/f7r5uu21cWfPaegpEdlpkQv05sZPIkTuyLSfandg5tpPsjONW0xJls6O/FuUfdZK9zjkX8wIz9/MI8yrnHc7VPMWe@qoAEpRk2eneM3vWZHVbJAEUCoVCoQAUqnTR4ml3cFrs@TCoQUhp@VoYTlyzfsABjnoxHIz98eDx44osmkJmu3n1y5ohPOsPEInO8rxPul57EET93Jg6tTU464dR4Ck4Rf0c6GVHoGOBZGw9WT8OokxGm3bJMhagha@g6jabYT8cN5sOLCbdSmw3zgaUYM9cLoP1Lz1Z5Uk8aaD7Q2dw@mvQGru3w0QYCV3sKGx9dvaHOhE@OGqKZFiL9H9KPScNRkWDZOXILuqhSp@OHY5/cj7oDc5I67uICtiHzUyBbySwgZA/HDIunvKxpK1YwUR4lDgtz3d10Z@@u6j6adXx3bj8ahpAihieGk3TGJQdzamueWN1UszUd/j9@B7a@B4uxpdX4dM4y9K8KonfV/UjJ4FAGRM0Ht2OBppOcqs9g04Klfgz9CopcGcU22yw1gamNcpa09kLHeIPL36L6C1G/P1N9F/cgaZ4/a7d59OwV4cTkjc92H6K/5zInMM6lL3hQvbMVhez9s4d66K8iNu8CxWC1FgWXH1416aBiUhPUbyBbADfwvOwEZvhezYcq0riHJxGl576vHpzF@0020HXnwRtR@f0LLimxQe0YGN5dbeGQ9Cx0BvIWs@hucuNU2kaB9ElU@UGlvG9S9e9ma0kSxhzD@@UM4aNm@mH9BnRjC2@quxW0zogl1vGduxliO1PRLiSAA5diRyp5ajMP9KTcKlxO0GIDjJ7lr2kWneR@Dxw4ibdYUaI8xbSTYZ/dQMR3rJm@/D7SHR7S6lzrUJV08uZdOii@T0eLupxiysMT8qx091Y8jamuzPPWawmwBIRtv19U8gMZBiPtFqODVG@LOyxQX9GJuAb79P1b5hVmnMEalySJd045OU26xduBivjBv1iw@k9/QLgWTBuCkOZtmFPSwdjVpzS84eW1qK/kJJOUCwqCsk1GlaujHmm7F@@xXW2bqyzNVNnK1VnPALSVVqZMq1UlboX0D2LuqAbdMY3SGckYe1MP4vENv3rD/wRdiu@5MJcJfRU7jJXIYGcC3KVukNCOdfOVXb4IcpVDvnhc67yEz0kYyv3NVcxwwIZRvTKDy/wXYtwvLdylW3H/ZYZ@5@DyNRbyFXiPqU8P8orU4RIgXaT1ogjtv5AN3M8CmhiY6XSU@CYyMPyifdhPP6/RP9JMDIOU4RE7HE@4MzqoSqnJg1rxpB6aNowYTDmjOSKns3r@7tsfBVnQTUPaY1nl2HwpIYv59LCSBBDKp9o0C8hCLlZmY@RsmayO6KjaycO5U5O1y8RFlkfaDucfkyZT5JKOAKdLm/6Kw1COvBueKLwTXjOoGOqY4xwJuvOQQtE/SW3oFHo6zQuuvftHuK97nQmwjZvskgvMVhLppMOx4dzHKNyMEwzCafC7D@0y/CmnAxKcO9UMZYKemTekMyfdcsgGOzB7y5qjlUOqKVEEBKPSycyyuJ5gWUxkhJZZ2mqMvgIBUvm0AgPWp85ut@OfuR8Im48nitumoZMWamSJVdaTFLhAlyEXfhjqT1evNbhOOz7lq@m5DX2WhwAsErGtYh8HXyH/j4Q/d0o1IYIUxXMU6znT6Wz6vXCWXYK825S7WwHItFTO@5c5SiuISE5rQ4szXwRr82o@DD5ECVfKo2hT2n7hmzxmuAWuk2vLQQWtITRZfrj51X6@Hn1ZkLNaiTdy4JRWgqoScORhseYJk1bjKs0fF4XI4X3t/3ud3fwKN3BducBHjdgNEVyGeWjiz5buSRjm8S2fIFILVeUCHI@Lo27OflI4p6PbuNjW/qw3zzY2d97/ZEm3SdPnrh6jp4k@GHUYq81nscFMltyx/PBnGXLqocQXDjsxnZ8dD4Yje996mdnZIkIa1IGfKrFsJ8e466WZZY8nxq7VE7yWhTVsD4nw8BPSSWoOj6m7FDTdUwECcbOA18DMeot0dvj1ZrLwaaazb7fC5pNnr5MIHk9i6FrzIm4@/fle8WLaMQB0yVS2lUmwy401M6@@vCqdqSOXtXV7rvtn9TH/XfqQ23vCM4Q3r7bet3YVvR/fe@wrjIpUzxElcSCkui6E7QCxApWq6XSY8WQtwfDicgdZ9uV74d@T70atAIcUz2P/N6Lc3kp9IPxppSq03J0gj3MkKOI9sIx7C047CUtY6HctPmqIq4eKMp7SmvaHta8vUE77ISUN4O17zAMInO7TXVD6kGSt@aCtydKEiJcsukQR66FBdYVFfcpP85uCIwv9lcgMXJISMx2QWnCxf@@m4JH9YM3hwp@Nbb393YaR439vUO1u39Ar28/NvZeEj0bh0cHja13SOKMb/Z3GruN7Rp/EARKBQWHF79eROOFKBSQnanS@oyT78KQuj9@S@96Q4NXVz5f2oxU7qIP6RP63fD3oJ3byFxEUF9wUZSPCpSzUjt4@Z7mfBX8hhNOcxTM9gfZdxFHXV0pqedcGw2WTRpvG3q40rSXL7t8HtGbKAReCjbYEYbDz54ywNmIpx0GKrsNGxXsfYu/DB7LBjRVdI9gA5QxWKkqDpiWy3nPGeQm1dbqDuB2VWoTI0L9gqIvjKnJRoYppm1lABSXKxp97AeVN@IPxPf0YVVXOx5JBvUo/iAZ1GP5AFW0AdsRtaZzXIz3LyCe1bp8@LU33OVjYfUk/rDl8yr2qcZJ@o271FdxwEl4D@lyWDzZ5eHQveIMBkUizo@Qcd2uDIxAgpWSTJSjRLZto5xZEjYdHDVoszcJAo5U4gbYCfmdcaScqltQRzAOCvqhBCQ86/p9MYFKTHeY99RTeHaq6jvhYRzIj6@rDAfMgAgimsYjLrejtcLgruWo5NZMjb62keRgusYE7TYEtmYQ@CNgCFA@tdJp8UzF92gBZtDRrOxEA@JI7Nv@zc5P7Ny@aAWpAtpqy/k1/P13VxPZS62TjJ0iY0dd9HswIrWSjzI7gxGNcRarHPoMUrB1PhiOQ@lDJ90CPnHiaY5yY2Kj2n6pbqZqAx2ma@wP@lalp8TFN9R6Skx5l1qZ4@XsPBZfSUxs4nyahMXuDuj4p4PLwDo783CIdBVg@4UUYT4rx@bnZMyYiP6ZSWTH3xRC6T6tbu5sfcr/7RcP8XRFLEg4a2N0iP@JMVEXDQ8@52ODxRH0Lj3STBzE6OIUpbUNnpaWGOUGGK0Dz0Na171obsRpYm48@x1Xeaa/88evX6tSKg/JpGOgR@dOIt08dWyq9LjMidImIJbsJGRJ1jvmi8cwY3n9Atd30AvwPNSHHMG6fSrKoBYhpnWnFx2SLDrYs@7uGL6rNtmiwiiS4izC7o/iz85W9eGmW0wMSpRFTseIaM9ALruuZZbC89UMuJ3F4Eh@3x3c04XYyfTwXdB2FkL7LtzyD2@GJdOSBevuYP@2AKxMbn8ILLXduxmwTJKz0GJOj5nTW1mOrWkX1/jLTN/x2CMwmHuxgxIDtWq76PMRtXFi7kgB1waTKESHRzv1gwOVlfUJlSW5hyVDW4tBwL6n3ibWtmGfhV0hVprixXKsPJkvKYs282/RYJ5LvBtEhdZBPE2PWFgkrtI74bVIPT2zsArB1vcsEA3l0th9MTIoOtaAv9EakJBNOs1qYGZuM5dl8gkj2whc080T3di24WcLa5m7EUJ5NLEB2TZB/hlulszvvw@iH1dMPaJgwesSGtwmTZrmG1onHFLFQ8pYKKR7cEG3mC6Fkb0o2MuGdjD8KqU17D/PUMxIooSLLmyJda0ca9REP14xag4bJGIa8GHpqRPFopkSjIjnL8/tDnWTSc9JT0GkZCKo7gubK6j4yTc9hTE14nmyGivk9lhbYWyODZYn2J3VsDduznQfttDr0@JhuiqStguryv9jqpJZIlWTofncxphEgry@tvboNtjTrTDF838Wtswh0/Jz3BvS@j4BGU0i3t4nzm3seSY9YYAFpBPTejNgpgqSqjNnTkm1nScjGz/CRfaFCBkEAkCc4ulaXXU9hdt86DIj2dA5y0wbrCEcN1RGzQz1vy2uDgL51vrufX99MtiQCaaD32CV/2YwioLkVp7lT8b6hHv46W/BaNTnbHKfqQcoDl9jWnjZjm/bicGrtAqJfN5mt6SjbyeJ2a1n9hq4Et5eLCA0OXb3Nqa39/LlDbupu43XdfWA/W12UnuR2VHWtWTPvbC/CAGWwbwvgemD7/Ddjyr0P@HgGZBEJr7N5zBt3FtxY4qQ1nzMoaG0WaiWreXp3u9ELb8PDyRe9n6kst4PVJB3Yev7u@68nfXSRqo8IRcN@w6V8rL5QpaL0jds6AJSGoT0Jr5bExZuahhLSVyvORvAPgoHW8G17J6x5aRfLD8trT/LcOv63tjrHT878R60qllFk6/f70UXo6v257PB@WVHddXw19Pr1uT335Raewwv2mr1B/GSXF6vFtnP7BMFB9vPSsy5GsEf2eMzQmUXJIawUjmVrMM37imXH3jRXMENiSkuVQ96hgtxxW5c7R2vn1T71dJG77h/soFLfuOH1fHD8kMHH36gWZRkjJzMH49PMKfau65B/1LBtSjHqtVXQxRfDaEvb/xROHhd23uZ2o2DAoAtMG3rzRvqEpZ8CdZsuHtS6AdXjt4m8xQ4NgMFKbPEt4LKuPTO@8nYjmmHhBn1ikfabHTNfyduZqlUuBiOB5xi/EGCtdTX8GtmyVxjKvGOAmU5Do3XSNwvIDhJHgcHQ/J1IlbU@bKoa2XcnXQtEMcoyeIw@ymbxZ1CIKrvch2fZKJC4LfOgUSX1OqvXEw9f67wRqwWFXgXD6Yc/ogvTJRO8IgDEPoZ8mkDqmDNPeJrHxlqPt7LeJAvvEc15nsybCCfYU0RKTD/Vl/4fhOXf04EEMIvic5V0FucWvMiRVLuDvLmApytpRf@OGbAtUrplCU0FrClvmoCnC3FmUaoVpOJvi9dgZxCK/qnW5Av89tMM@L8rmRnkvA5tX6LQEvuUk7axE83KeZYxfKmmMlskWLpVmpgp4uWR28CGlYTtR10u4S00GIpIQce@X6vrv9hXH90jDpPYuQlPT@Tnk@lFyRdkEpyFWiCTzJV7EzZ5S9Jvm8qm2TzZuqqKlZeCtTTrQKpJEnejUV5o8J40AyTzJtxVwpXxgnPUwl5K@XnOb0vKfdSZWIGj9OPJV3z96ru@RjLVN4X6frxm9EdFLDxrLY1meLSQj/s/pjRIdx1CtgsS9RUSopzUE1lBlVV38HU4oQ0OOzz87DdrCZQHpaNxOExk918/iJb0ErGj840GnKLcWZgzRkjFpW4zodMuGu@sEj1cPI9CwTDBKMpM3I3TeGJLjyxwCLXPVOt3IKcGeDUtOkhXsW9yK/4YwZ7GjmTb3l@4pJgfi2Nl9vNaQKx0L2XnU@mtDTBdRH5qBu1YBZJ6p5MQ5wvJPasXeC4zkDuYHewDX4vlhO2oDCSYobucYqmdJKhbNj3pi5E4rfM34sPMi990rGH3eBa1bDM8PkWViZ1wX0cROMIPqjYPU50MRx2cerICt8VX6HWjv9X13DckkC0ZvZCpgHLHsnv4UlfSKdCBbUPyFcwEEkSoouzM1wmww3YwRVEK3ZcwnEhU@tPZEODxsyjVblmHig432AB3A3PbCSk52T0gNLR0G8FhQzpaBFpPxlpaifUsWh5Px33RuDqjKa0SibzLxdh6/P2S5znPimXHpUtkl3q4@BS4dHj5IIVEckkrMJb4Vr5cSZjnQ235Gw4D4Ceeo2J/j3xZnAZ9PtBpkYzBmeMSGmNgtFl0C5kMgdBfAgMuGBlnEziHvbgYtSSzR1SunxiRtwSjjw5DiMOwy/mZzkubvFZmZfBoVVy2kxdfRm2QUBz46QzwOkwH1jATYDQA4V6wZiI8sBVaZT47FnjwrpLDxtRRA34ObHOJmIy9AfjsEU9wztZmS6BkmOQpLJ@ewoTqq/V9XE5uDAPAVyPSShgEDBHSYtwyOhD8@/CQemGmTN23/RMkaTfgMcKDfdgFJL0TQjMvcLFLNypg49eNQ7V4f7u0YfaQV3R89uD/feNnfqO2vrIZ9w4KGdPwOrV/muSLvFpupya79OHbO2QSmY5IVPb@6jqf317UD88VPsHqvHm7esGQSPwB7W9o0b90FONve3X73b49J0gqL39I/W68aZxRNmO9j2u1RTLJOXU/q56Uz/YfkWvta3G68bRR65xt3G0h8pwql9Tb2sHR43td69rB@rtu4O3@4d1hYZldhqH269rjTf1nQLVT3Wq@vv63pE6fFV7/Xqqofsf9uoHio0ErFZu1QnL2hYtYVETt3OncVDfPkKDkqdtIh4h@NpTh2/r2w081P9ap@bUDj56Guhh/V/eUSZKVDu1N7WX1LiMcwtVqF@23x3U4T4JlDh8t3V41Dh6d1RXL/f3d5jWh/WD943t@uGGyrzeP2SCvTusewpRKrlqgkHUonR63np32GC6NfaOaM549xb2Di518gciDGFZo6I7TGCYQaC1RKT9g4@ACjpwB3jqw6s6fT8ATZlaNVABFhXbR3Y2qpCIeGQ3U@3VX75uvKzvbdeRvA8wHxqHdZc6rHGIDA0YZHwk1qFK33Gr0U@ElzwSs2YM53rcnaqxq2o77xvAXOcmDjhsaG5hsm2/0jQvwC@wtYkSDrBn4PfsjZXO7KfLAJ4wZ3dk5u/RxB6Ttvd36jQja2dX2SThHc06T6dcKdlpNNPEifSaclnTDk4vzpphvzPAHdO4mGx89KIzDyGRXISH@ZRZEJFM769wgeXlZvN9rUkL3cNm0/XuUjKFxm0l9Db4olyubiOiQGDljY2fSkXo/jxFqM0f9EEnG@rhAAI5hfo/iOmb3wtcVSy2A10Ml/cB2GwdRXJsco6jFBKNfNkRcW2SKnlngt9DzQ5c0DHgC60m9klhGcmZBhH96X9NXmRysD6QdJbtrmIRi1hGI/w9MNVIJewSgf9ojwRhh6ssREHw@cwp2dVhzV84GwzajuuaMpx3TOvAM8e9pfhpcDZVPD9dnpHlY2cdQCEy625WYeLzZ00ypfulMOKWOfjTHPOPa7ARnw/YNeWqeLNab1o6P0hxWCR5Sru2wPUK7mTofG9qf218wGqutPp4Y@r7q/i7jC3YC8JnLk14x1zuhH9enUgGGmDsi4NIEmoPGcWiVcbYm8SZryjjOTJdhW1Y/tBcfR7wvE4kIUX2wu/adWI2HoXXNvYkh18e1N5svdvdJdEJbB8/XXuyvpGJ3W791ZPfj6iH3dqy17EhzeOkp3GSNUq2SfHhkWJ5FU/Ynxm4WERGeJA3ncYf4echtttIWzJBkKG5EYI89WGilw1Ah6xiBxz3MoZf545MzQBOqqkuWtPzr1nF90lXYh7QxizdCffaNf4Adjz8zRCPG6QZSLMYO/olzqXVBcu97K4xFeXFDTvuQZZC1vCxuHGLacBbXWw/i9u1/KZ52@rFSEwZMV6527kkIXFvGgtl7Cr6MrLfsp8RvQHM3sPoy181v9HjR@3gjt3d@dG4Nj4kMu7GJbFPnWxG60Yfa8gniOgBp2qmpucKu/yuRorHnt5Ojh2DWKOBUUF4Gtj4pgFvxH5EpqtkC9gXOVd9EU6F8w7A2dAcq9@Jc@c1R0PZMP5D9LvxSqEEVuzkRKh2FdeRMVk@xn4sDDlTZPpT9GD4/0SazIH/nFacBD2hluUE8E6UZKhCK1q@MlHCK3PQYJ1uJNS0P31MwHyzO@Y8bpg@vbmW@zVEAt07E/PhI7s97DhzCAAmx8aGPX5jk7Rzn5ZOL7KuLo5zkn6rN3SUnivMVDEDN79@4rHa5ZmzFby4ypW9JqvC11RUvZCF2ymPeloyTS3l1f0oK@Bc4/@j@IA3QOIBz1x6Llar05xV0qPMyAHtasmacNqxxyRSS7/deGr3QFkuMlOyX598GUIR6E3gM9tODm0yUGKem/a4yDOxOmIveHBejmUyJh/tsu6UDTG7AeDcb/NmCKKfjK8wQXQFOrvqS6Ap5z4biqCSxOow8TMIcesWiLQ8rV7F2PPOJDg0xv5dX/zmB7KrZXIUxMGHxtC@Ll9Qb/wJody9W7OFxYoPDgcebBdRmWxL6PKI9NIaDEakOvpoN@HohRO3oD7oTYegH12MtP9Cms/Ckd6RMEo/VQO1SVbvPM2Iw3pGLQrHuK3QLjB/cJN6ASxExT3JdX5dOcS8hkc3zaZjeP2wrJznScpzogm7JWUiPlfr6utXySUE1S5DA6ZgGMWLC7bZ5Hpw7hAPv6vB6DPmfqhA/XbQjj2TWiB5L1A6qdFnH4@tsTR9OIh4R4O6AjsgMSXKspEWG6rSHP1Es5O2a8om3jHhu5Rb8v31xExqrKWoooRxde3EfOt56kxQaVW7Bo2dhZZX1xiVeQuubzcuxthbaPrYWmU/9WORUhElonrfqI54ErkZP33Ek97kr96PMHroC864tQoKhKGz4lx1Vs4xfrAp@BAGo7a9J0qaTNsfYvuNlz6DPvOi2TrUbv9a/jgKJrQCaBXD6yLDaDp/GZz3m9uDrn8WDkKf1mnwNn8tEg@PE35Eh52NBlcRBzGSyIxWpvYkeRb/MuKGDe/xueSG5ZorGgdDxzZTGI8mtXNxE8E75zACTCKvMn8Pp32kxWUeryWFMun7p2yPV3Y3biz7qDyvsJzoA4AWcJtTFhRyh3TMF5Osy6cbMxlOF2WwcDxVeeW7N1jspTB@RiTiY5gUxgaZGbMEuxFYmd2I8XH72muzD8IRHC0FOwHC70QOf/Z8RL8mKfIjLAUqqvy0ZBWVU5Rr@CHEw@Rmcq8@@SdjTwj8CfTLj@ZxyzxGYBHXMd6WIlmvaC@jhAubB4Yso1kSkxQLz8K@df2QY11cT0NNJ09uogZb/pBSpN3szXAlRqRDCx/E2nOaJHKaExeTSk7lXPbbARWkNnZKNzNscJv9LA9@HOLKzhkE07aG7FhI30SqFlEJ4YKnzGttlMWn8u0jZnX1rr02RcDqPJMzK861kzWaC99ACWV@xbHWYETCODtFPW3qkYvGg2HujtS7UXbM9cw2j9Yt173VEFiYrUqT5YM2k7Y6weNkIzONzxTTpCnGlmbEQ1i@8nPM5tNEvK42Md6qzcktdLiJZondVDypxP3dlrGPSfESFr1moomHFOMOJ6Ub8ffjJjW8ebME0TBledVkidGEyGhO5NECNUWmmEp3pxBzn8Z9ih5tohzqbRPt7P65kajTRnLG5alJSjm5BD3huB2XNkkuDTswvoCbONFwYyEVK5zX3oSP8sr5UzgZRoIAhFYc5JN9KNnBTTprio84OkDHacJaqAxJRE@btoVD7PQ/Jhh75debO9rioTnJl082BNJ1DIlWFZxrESRz35xej5vXDGWGFDTE55AibtGMbDq/e6v@bFsoH0GQ0pysLX1LHhrjqoeEDf2xk5rX0IGTqnTJ1IhKD4QmiwYaC7RKOesGslyF9heOhONh3aCHES0g5LODn4e6BNx5r5diaqPIdXuCLK4mt4w2V@U3pUjCUPIO8uuhKKouL1wJQCAYU/lqmSDArSljj0MBdr1jc14KUd1HVLBaxrCkj@wVNbHznJMOouoMj9esHKV5OZ7ZMPJzgZBiMT9PggjpLPOzJFBoopuLi5Xjyfz2JDlIITa8LxSnrtC9kqZh3HNCQA53XXITiXJcVl5JczAnPl5zU4kxf3Pqs5KVWppOJfrEGB7ny9OpT0up1FS1q6vpoqmSRA/XrjWVSKRwbYRjqfDn/vHVFNvleWwTai0yUlqGts9GOHJaZdK6rfBrpJ7zpWyjYxh49s1ws/xqSoiVlFP2xQ7YVY6PDOC7/U@31limGkx0rAD2S2cuuziyIGSNNYupHs3CStd42osdFJg17aCj3h/t7qbcvp5OjKFRLxitlUolMPGp7fze2FZjKykcFNO5i52Lbrc4vPrL6P1pkWV/EHBIgIpZQQfUJTQoosJgdCaRIYADZUXuvL7IirX@Radjh2DACSU6j7pNcmpvCIonoDA2enl/xBtADFJPsL@ggWjfLyoefVe@KJoaijmGotIwCb7MmtMzIg8@dGCfHZ9UMTAIZmPNRPOWW938ghkEkU24s9h9sfslMU/Ovgq63YGnPiAMMjwFLH2bLrC7axcoSRacMPLt3ouI/dF6KrgMu9a9YmSxeR3gzMRk4kwYv/DwjX8QnNWvh072@OcsTSvU5Ido5kP4p/ZU9izramfxdwArfEho3yl3zx86LabTdGaa6vUITp4Io0dlb@7aJ5XF5T0xTbPbc4Oo89EtsLMGarrLuoDxZc/dyy25IXtM3Oyn63IHNCwJDI0TfK7crQSumv3zxOLluNO5m1TkMADSsd8lESUSyp8TiHwGwCNQDz@iJ7xo/5SnYb075VBEFBwE65iVOyjQRIFM5n6r@tuVU6vV1Mrw4UNVq23RQz6vals1tYMPW1tqh9638P5DdXVtbUNk7o77hT5umY/f1BbB4B3Oh63z0Q69UloV98ZgrY0uXilWV7yNlWb1@eZGVDyubeFaPz3957/91//89/9WrOmX/4GXLX45/jnOVCgUiiutLys/fNvA@/HOSW7l9HhleJI72wCX/Z29hg8a47yfmI8WRqeZZZkFrK9sR2rW2ex9RhdVJqZfzx99JulSUcutqLisv0YSOYpl7HIrsL4HuEd5Skt4E3RgeilPSCwT0Am246l3WgEM8Gi@IUoSLrADlfJytmI27uEOJs4Qn6osa088rLNeBrjTknhSwF1cmrHyYT8K@tgBv2SdV5qXyfj0G46bmn@LP7@JzrYG1@rBJ0c9KKkHnnqQzfJPef0ZfXVXiiFu50o2Wg5ksx6lJEcLMDNUUciKHq8fONbOFLkzmRUO2QNIxk0FZ5ZbcF68@uPLMhJwLTrLLCHip5ItEj5kQpHlLyv9b9QtXyjHt2zqqg0rCk29iuHKrBOVuH@hAvmRGAIkNfeEIJUBVYmTPr6RjKei@aL7OsPRhBgwyHrwcpfHPT7QXLTS1zbPqbUUwhyx@bx8xdy4IZehGW2kSP0JAnygIsvJEt8kzC3nMmLlbbWSmym3sO32aeYTW4dJMDa26VLob8piArHmtgm30tf3WrQhtxyvqGwYH69YVWWnbb9VxirSu@iOw6G@rsC1Y0B9iWv7JiMJPcqABI747K/MjjDeKDCeoqa6RYJlTVR7gKbLSOjrq@nUwW5BTo4sIhR/dmhsf50a226Rb4kYdhAeYKRiU76OH3Yj7XVlxMQ@80eniA7odzig2ljOzXg/D5FbpzAedGKkCwyZTc6T8UxNWR6O/LOe76nlvcHRyJ80aNoizWfcKrjUQrhgAhIYfLrqec0zCEuLdJcwReKmsOUQghd0Jzo8mvRtNr5zgi41Q0G7XcEgSLETUzL4muqrKTomXP0dnWCjPCO849NILWJZ8sLSSEPK2tdmeJjNDJ2MqcEeO/HAyWYE1XhkGl7QhS4w0fb44JckeRc@AnTdWX0LUF9FWH@G@jE7nQV9PzU5DbsZc9G/uKFkXsR45lCUYo2U0VCelJOId8CK9Mif014gZG4y7owyS46z9CnS4dyW7XmEnXzHtvhFX4VxADoOYMY3Q9S7fijCcmqGSmJgFFSDLf8JQqfrnxF@kyt/Alb8tOz8eK/oHv/8qX/ywPnU//rpd5cx0SLZzLJ5tawPs43E0mOFZsail3o1VmmRcTX4qZ/O8Kmv5A6LRQJCpOgc/1w8@VokhD4tu@6D4qdlIUiqy4BJcXF9RYAvzqC5nMaiuJxZch@4pvOdH8uuormVf9GH8sGVX8LCLCp5m57WOaMOgeJ7ur9dyJWTqPh0tfR4tfyYVkJnwXV@FFxgvs1HF6fBNakSEZazNPV8@j3FDSlCfLuO/A36eE3tlLAmcvck0peUtAjVw5zrycRsRWUKwhOUn6jM7lJxxcWN8/g4fMSC31PEciYv@4IS00GL@xzMn9Ggh3r8CHJt@naIcCSsDMRGhLdQ84Bsgq/cxKGuGS45vudUUNvw3cpAqHuLy9Zs0R/081pZcwu5DSjRuDXTfVp6WpoeozNDNDVCV7Qylbunyps/PvmP/77/2/J4eXO1@GFEv@Pl35bXny7LIz3Q2yPzdrm8ufwc2da/LU@KtAamxyf/8T@p/OZfCA5SJs/pz@aagbU@Wd7MV7nI1@XNdXoor65Svf/rX/@V2rAiKzbEYl1peooR2zAU2fb7zLuUrhpopSxLc4lY4YtZgCEWhrQ2pxcYRl2vPi3xNt2ytqq4DLTnK2OPoqd4Nswas6mQ7GQYewrSjKRAFRXkBaQxoegoy3bDmG2AeRM01S/3C@sRrQB@0eYccZWx6cb9CCZDK7Isog50pEZaz8vDZunHbGzeUckam5INo0Jiaadl7dNHG8QObwfBOGylrSTMcO21/KvgtAA@LATtC1pT9aPu4NdR8ZJYsldefVrsYHO/yHbcxSFDyg8nhd9JEdTBgGhhyEannhpRDwx6cOHlcbQgUuh34zMpE0@StOxh0JI9rHRMYsoid/w8OR5GcwqJKu3wX1LgETlTB4K0YqV96lPJ/YOKyj6MM0o@XvO6wOYtG8dqFxh5sYYdsmwqZLgN2B007SnURmd8CYlLweu6ZCn47XbT12lOZilrQqV5maXzoDusZjvi3h2@U3FioukvauaNUPIhdhDyeRZ0gNULxj4t0atZ/oL1eFID3KTos9bYVVxC1o7Oq1f17SpHXVlQ9ZVUfUU9Ci0hqSfmGcsbm7KziWypYqtyFDRxpDa3YqotMkGbRwX@AQaRdEujg2sJujl8A5KoljRHW5XZ3ebxWph45CqQO3uytSiRqzPLyeVHz@SQG9TQnVBvQSojAQEvuBVYKNP7odyAqJowo2E/I/78ppKNfw8NhtuwD1eitts6cT4q01L/ErFvwjHfpVREAu1X1rbBzsjsEYOOXWzFIWiz2HjJumCpToUXW5zRdEeFw0Abl1DZrOxTHbdUHF62o6PXSqAI@pAtlVcfPV5bf/L0GaKcLenWzgeDQgWsAobnPsFgjdqhRTa@V6vZXFY@IQT1bJWAPg8sDuBg1nXlusbt85V7r1ouaWClLMO64jAaUlxvVzLIBOIoKGBGoDWKM8o6zo@VYzTs5FPb/Ur/E38b/4DMcMYdrS@kt/rhbeKZKtMThwNVFszsFMd5BA8qrk6x8waDzgG8TQSwdRW2p4pewwPE@Hw0uDg7t7mjoF1bHdGAIYKzX2qsoF4G48TBmIUVdFG94dCwbl9UDbzj2RbAKBdTAnQ@AU7DTPut9LWlKUZHjiYheNbEjVUcIVqmozY7M3f2B6q@tzON2LIdho7hFmzLVlLu2JMZHMggVq/V3COirvZ2wVdJtUzyUl6VWcCVkK/M1@F93JVuIRC1RRUjq1lvGDuLyFJmXkxcmyZFqR@B1xyY5dLtpDT3Wk0rQBAjCPVuUizEvPg8xyZZgpPdyRin4OVsxbIRfRNGETuY05VlXW1Rypk4qsBS5gaA2LcpZaUhpQp6lB/rHHhZehvBHOVWNLYGtBlyvFIN5ubkMBNsdRuJA2xEHTe0QPsbe9ue2qnTn90POx4U5a3aT2h3HOL5ZnzLGt9yRTV2TRfY3mLZ5hY2U7/hihIxS0k7jE0QhPDtSFTEIPEaUG/satrLoD5Oje2ThCvArr5Wws3uqB4kcPTCeyBLevEeu@Lg6zr8rSKbV7OSJnapooeFbHEtHtgWTZaSWmNIQso7gFidBhE7akm4fSlheLFAZ83b12sXw9iN3fk8nWJZWVCR2r5bJLKnefZGyixii1XNFqsV9OMivmC@Xcgbp0FnoO@ixcxxC2/c@2O8kb87c@T/v2CO@j@HOx5p7nhUgewR7ojdhvONTg7DPpjDMacTnoOb7fAsxP5Qx3pFI0qeBYAFHjDEHVJKLJfQthvEiXLmJzycno9gJLS6hosBf6jxj3XjH1cgc/lxJ/h/tfH5f3Dj13Tj1yqYa@b0vFbtLHfr/5gWJyqhk/4wt3uh7ko294@2dF23dL2C2XRON/9fb2n@/1BLn@iWPqnAY4IcOIj7@sXcLJpI7XC70UjMLQoZ7bTLQRz7@VzpYu3VrmZp8dDpXkTnVWjr6g/j/1Tj/xTSiJ8Qhg5nEbFtaLyWl@WpXJYXzZJ3ORQuWUlLpL3GM7rVXj1hJesRPUGJkOaNrZFeqJBC7klictpUSPTHRPrGk89dcRbZroNl4uDcWkDLirDsJkNcNF8dJHN1PZ5XdtgHsto@Onj98L8IGXr@Z30LjZBH114F3a6ZSewl2FHsdUo3xmoOYB/qNUeKVTQ5Gdmxvu0ds8vSzVKNHVtMzYvzFwly1IbzP1pL9aBvWFG5sWVEtCno8mZVBdNcs7yQL9R2yTS/ybrFf4hLn2kufVZRB3phcBOpfL3hp3kxWaetrq0tmgOkVAE/GIAlj/IvGFX/Gw)

[How to build](https://tio.run/##jY1BCsMgEEX3nmIuEIUsu@6mxxhHiUONCs7Q49skhIZCF12@//j/e@xpjIUFKNcSIYm0fnNuS5J6S3V19xhfjEXcqj31hhQNBbhAtAEXFtM1VNho19Ya899qwsyGMpYFpgo7zQGmx3XgmvrvwCvnMIXodTnk0XIrcrF0Qhek506/W5n9R9g5WBzjDQ).

`2y` is noop in Hali, so it is handled separately:

```
02y#v_"693",,,@
    >...
```

I finally figured out how to run [64-bit CCBI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250186), so main section was redone
for CCBI cell size 8: [perfect hash](https://tio.run/##nVbbctpIEH2WvqJDigSMiHXhZgN@sHddtal9SG0eMZUS0kiMgRGlSxy85W/3do9GBBFpwaFKjHroPnNOT880Xjf0vNfX91x468xnMElSn0efljf6z6kN20Txjub09z4LuGAg1q4IE7BtnYsU0sV6ls/MZ8M5TOFfXbu8hPxj7dSLnb@YVtem38wVvFP2il6cP75@0TXLAiMP6@UjjNRoqtE6sosRF7y/vf1L1@yRCrX6@di1yiPUjQjxZXefiZARSr@MUkvE/hXFCwqQq3xyAEcU6kAO1DAF4tgKpDf8XSZdy7xCoEHvhCSzBhiB7u4ot85gcATRqwmt4PKPd6mS6wyUFBPKMLX5OcjL5697lFEZpTa6AuVuHSVpzH2ebQhJpdixTmSmAkmy6XQQZWi@sWQOUOJit4dWNZWudcYBQAxOGPaZu1SBkaRcrJZRLAjHOYHzP1z@xvsgc0N2fX27r@Rhr3rbz0nzuwOY/pm0KmA2Oy@S0opCHrydyiIICEHVsAVvZ/FnEiHCaHRmvVSk97lIRnHFnMxpxaH@XJykK/sI5A1F98xDyeVqREBONdA5kgTfFEAv45@9xuffoZW3l47V1nVv6cYXELKUzq8IW9SBhCgaUFvH5pOkbso9IE/IvWaEcgEOdMCSHQoZ4iIa9raEpa3cyYCP8NGAhD@zKFBzbeiC1UZPXQuiGORqjwhgjnGYqEaI751OW9dwaU0uKrLNrDfHKC0RW4RJgxZOGbQ3jWbX8RuGbJqP85k5b49JfD59DTEPl2l36/qArfCJp0twIdm6Hu4SkfW2u9YHJclBQSj8cT43QKI7xPNF17WYpVkslPSxjlNEe@Ny0ZL5kUoykfBQMB/WkQjzL54L4yisZWXrNUwm2LouYIAc@V4hsn1iRDNBY49CK7gY3@JwcyOjzDZ8APOHcz8@9luU/KxaP6/kZ9f6@SU/p9aPlfx6tX5Bya9/6McDaLk4ucDHw8fHh@GDIVNSjLcLXqAZwwJG51JpUvjpGpIppsgLiKMn9MoLhYI1uds4RQTwxxmWckcyIcMmw1OGQ4avjB4ZTBl9MgJlDHJcuSIKy/EnpCOM0gi@ldSo5ZtTOpL7uL2iVa5ohfGPOORicjUF@GpOWZIwv6wg/61E6zVPOF3QGhayJouZ6i2IMuHDlsUB81JYuskS59XBaqhinM6atg8VD1JuNn0QU/x6aDSTh8aDwAPoGrAwwDPAN4AZEBgky1C7YRxcMEK025SAPddrecxeXl//Aw),
solution:

```
weights=[18 45 13 55  6  1] %23 n=22 "11 393374366369375377370285329364392367372376289368371388   389284373"
```

Answer (score 1):

## 405. [CSS script](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/css-script), 17090 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{ #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; x=echo 403;$x||echo 350;exit#;a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295# [']; print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68')));[exit];'"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';#wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405









































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#8""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._# :
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({54b3de5f-dc33-49c9-81f0-93abcd8d21ce}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0kiwRAAHyzyOrq6urbfdUvdVffey2SzQZJkEQXCLABsors6uqQNLtay/bMejSyQ5Y9vrJmPCuvJ2K8EztreceeibD344RjPvkHtB8bG44N6x9ozzkJgGAVWdVXtje8CxJAPk9mnsw8eU4@DrqGP/rpTxN4sSeuvRja7pRNTX/K@p51Ynoyu71gtwzLL2i6IGCofW84G5vO1K8KCaYyZhvOcGYMTTaw7KnpZZlvmqxr2u4p@GuM7c6cmW/2G2DTGXPMU3bf6Vl9gMCm7rHpWG9MD/zyjN0x7bfjt1PWc8djw@n7bOJZzpR8C4w9McAymPWOmdH1p57Rm1quA15Fxp47tjHu9g1GwSeeySOVGIDqHVOcVZ8yYw9dzzchBbdn@r6LjhVwNDzLfbD/6KML4dUc@8iATE1sc34heVVln1qm178YQ2OfHN29e9FVZ1@RXIfdvZwlNc/2Z1P3/vQi/ALbH5qOwTS5ImsXPYuAzKlpl3Pl3EWvEtSnObV6K@mAx13Lg9o1glpkPcOB2sK63GHmeDJdMInXv2HbUd36zPDZzJ8ZNoVzZuOu6YUB/anhTS1nyE6t6YhNR5YfxaPQ/sTomVLftK2xNTX7zLYgkjsIoABop8@OzcWp60GVBzBdx15ARLNnDSyMEuYDAOKVmo5MDmdsLKCSnSk0DmYwH7JhmyG0tJCA8HfM7mzI3Nl0MpsyyFvf8o2uDUC7C9Y3B8bMnmZZF/wAyeR@OjKdoDEDOBlAHLk8V69mlDVz2eaNfp/loB1DPo5NZgHWKFtVpuvgzlwPsAahwhwFwKhd8zKac6gzqKKBW2WFXA78DyMXzK1h@26QmdWsoacDfZXqDOE@8dyhZ4wBG32TcPrJ/SfM77ke2ODGsLw/XQWmZ0zZ7i5LHj66k2SNqFpkrytEVVRnZ1AFidCTnRj2DFpIvCZcqB8vii1glSW3klWWBLRoOZbPszx02zLTCoAkNVcBA/R/TVfhLjKtzPIq9KAC07VSMotpDTxjaNkmhzRESCVs/BBEg2cuz3S1zEMOXXvAg/UowRLTy6xYYqUCK8GzwioapIjg80ytFOAuwg3QKpAdFW4dMpfTOLBl@4f2im3ugA2MsWUvghQoiR4rqKwEUCHfKkDXygAF3rqOtw43ZW31isOejgDrI@MEwEu2dYxUyYwIE1alAi9lZ0chyoiklyfvjzB5QCEgr1BmJUi@CNjIQxYAw1oZki/keEH8kWnbQbSRj9Eot6Uc3JDzEuCiDLWQA3zmEKEluMEOdE8DAqcBNdOAQGlAVDQNzDomAeGK4FeEKi3meTIjwz@GhHg6Wp8qACg7gFER40jMVEQSQIAaY4BqqO48NAgdG0RBZ5B/yEupyICelVVWzrNyiQE@KzkG9aNCvrC1qEBHVciPisCgDajQCFTIkwrYVgGoqheYEEO2qqM/xNUhLqBGzUOcPJih4tQi3hAPWocKSaqQpqZVlo0R8qYVoLwFnVqpVoTaLYEf4E2DvGrQpDTIrVYGf4xbBhyWsRFD0@WIMBAPUCvY7KEtAjIKkB@CC2HBrJV0jj/DnoyMLlJtHrM7wKhF7A5FRCNEzWHx4J1HbEJWcgAGewJkX4MWoFOvgXc@St5WAUgTwZt9iwi1bQENUyMMlbLUIF8Zk@kSbWqRcjRZTEeRm8bdXCCgFhBBc2j0FpEn9MBs5Ll0LeroqhHNXQLK5dHVBwrrznx7CSQy5DVKyjyx7KVbmdz6ptEfWP7o3TKveUqkaxpTxzpeplIoZGNINWIeRfRYcSrp8bBTS4JhazhC07IsWgnDTNyoglayrKqUva45mDlDU6qUY/kjn@nMm8IAs0yzwp09aziEsXkJR81SMWnAXDoXKIe2rk@FyBGxi2l6FgzjN1lvBIxF5Fnh8CuVJQxdQxgLo4ujuwTcGIwGFRy/BtacdW/2aPRYZlAnPPVG1iQMXN0YOFa5lMi8XIy1DcLcm3IuIs94teVXruWkkiyZFs4FGHM4hxkfsWFg@xRHKxx/senC@OoS97AknyknHCHTgLTVwR5GXxvIKFRKz8CRGMclk8bVEI41lRkkAuyg6Z4g@0qD40oyPg2gXQ@5VeB2@qbnMQwLLK6fpaHWn3V98/UM@allvgYwdpswxA8My44yQOOIMSVGAN5JH9JbrGZ74LljGmzGOJTarjvZwLbAwH2KgO65p@Yy68tx3ZhMbOCewN3kzBtk5tQgvpuY9HiqPEMQCeNBhQNASgq4Dssze4T7oOgQWwf@ZDWLVaY1buoI5XaMrdKhswDL4WMcZ2bbVeB3zB7TG0rfPFHQhbNeqywX5iFkxoClCkB0DeCZMeeUiwjSTU0mNu8orFnfHa8WjY@v96OijyxkkOxTYwG1N4Ch1ZwbY@DsGbLP0HPZGFoMr0GsCZBdsFj3Wd91ktMIyqkHzCwUOioJMcyIk6k1NkEKciEK1nieMo2jO@Wsu4CmTNjKyyT28JxcQJQsXEQUd8jHHHhnAbavP@sh1jBty6EWBKySj7y@B6SSuwlTj7VaBtwe8HWTQNKT0YABn2HWYoKCz3t7wIH3CCLyqqbjg3jhy8xCOQxa/tAdQGM7taDsQLAg6hJ2j5CAKIic5nJPFgjl2IDGxzazWG8yYeAOgxI0z7u5MrCi7iuLvQFPewSiRG/meQs2n0BNWGMINe25gwG03jfmZAQg2LjPeosedE@oZGw9Qt8lAtObrBZzads2IYyDwsnBk59nQxPQDozrAKVUbPLLAkwmVARCheFwptYxAFNYhN5kQWgREssYA9eV0b3vmj41Ftc7jro@JuabQ@oa0M8GS2I0RiYdWqlDwkUfKE/QvRA@JiisLQwmFbSCj0wHuk4PWiV0eqg@rNN9NgBhO8bCorxh9HrmZBq0E5fImeXE@P7Hd5HvJ1cpACb7I2H7Ftu90GogaNRyYrwsykGY9UkgjhhIawOJXiLGIxI9OWWxF5eShxAnF1IXX2KYlRy8FDfkYUJdAoUgIhKzKZISpI5Wb4S0cIrUhvht6G3e7HLxwS2evDdm0iBKG3OjAtkRZCVywnxshiHBbV8GJE9shNVYccCgKw7XgDb88RrIbpRJux93lRVDBqJ4HdCx67hroAIyI7gYZNWH6oIa4zOkGoYdNUbqLv5KHSHBXk4y4UAGY@hk4nrQMzjRWdCMAlVZrHUFgngqGivSMru9OrTCkJHEAX@KoyBEmNgGtAXsYthTQbIygFIAEeOCMtA8l6cYyzD1eoIV5O@USD9vTDCWOo6JwpnhLTgQKB4Mz5DQglmeB2TwBAcJPgaFg4lM7RTGBKPfR8qK6KB@fzFxGVv0waxrzS9K4z10lF/5wonhsQEK4h4wHdCJUsmBn0zXyJ1ixrxExZ1MFYrKnyIEpEAyVHlqALI9DBJ3gdA8Wzi9lLjSxcQsE2fTQVlMgwEjch6NfQyiwsXcofiAjWZ8DP2abDU2hOFbkuApoRvlBD0UGT0MD/gM6IQgZVYq/a7B3gL18Jg0P@CiSCiSqHI@Sst0@lFaASIwL/HyyjwJ3@uRQYqNalgCDE4lp0FiBYEfiAmKKIKDogRjKzoQt8f9iK/hjjOH5uNYirMiaXYWMb8wAKQoMxYwH1bPmnYCduXmzZBx2arXobEBNwVks5@OS7ThxKUMlBoCy8SNBInIU/fZFPtGKg3lxcDnPDfANkFLrTfY2XTkQY8j@7kAgQCtgoMtOURsUM@PrONZ/2JFO@iIgUTsdcA0Wb2pWBNg8Oe9oX4VVpMrWAWpN4lYxcaL8Qn0pcZLrlihYhDMM31kf@tBVmI1nMIcBG11LYp41MBt2aAPFj07YAm4CTo7p0ZdyP5xMKEVEaJswBOEnfZST@VAsDtwOOzJ/tG9etAXuafStZzqioPt9gybnLcxuBjGfXD/9tP9pz/fWQPDtrrViw6KlS8XcaidzaWhM1PyslbdjsNYAr7TuRo2RlwNIwqBN5PceYxVWvRgcJmH6Hz89CsXUQKcEKKDUgAz3hdYGh4GmC6ha/ijC4MwG2YykGQUJQzLpPsshBkZMOvob4T5eTJ78wYr72KmJoE75syeGRxA6Kjcd8J4MnpeYMBCr@6Aj4gUF7hQy8EFh6UpHjLMz0fINV/MDLHSsSbz0eO7h0/rBDaYV5MoiOJPgZcyvL4Mbd6egQi@LgyQPzD1WEZeZhz5acrrWgT3eisIXtYt2wAfAKCsI7tMssdh0fwR5P3gYtnIVepFLYDsBOEiXxnnh3pfNKOxfOAQ10ORd90oSh7LwSpyWjtiRb6rw1avUDBL@Up82Oot0@zHgdLiAIwDId/ogdexL6GLvOQiA7Y6yP6zB5cy7hMTCaKAFObMt5lMafm2gNKLZLGkrxyAhObapvwpUTyRiWlFSYbrA3LPJ@EzFv5wbk1TuTR/q2kIC6nv79/X7oSBgylrmskgoQFlcRyZvAGu8/V8aCOOa7tDl@1AHM4dhgkC27SxmPtD17lUQwY6YlETuFQI9BcnbowJjDXWGxIcKVZcXOWLjobjnwKVVos6IokwRKAUCi@/Mk4MQNey3M/uf@0QBhG1kMtF5hxdgIJYHEIXmnoxV3JgEiQkB/lZW8Bo2fBSbw89pNi6HRY6IHRRxP2l91pHopiysjb82ix97F7C@Ct3caFpgQtvWmCIoez@oycP7j86fLj/WWuqFQor9nyuUgTEQXpd4IXkEccb9tYd3jWxWAguAX3Dw@4FVGAGAkq4ajTzPSDcMgaReQY2tBq@4Jr62B05ST99sTCn6Cu9cnq8CT3EzseDBhFB0O7bKIx4fNUax3NsP6PpdOJXFQV6@WjWlUFoVV71XNsYKhQPBgbbVlQUXe4/xnkNf10MyIy/MHkMPrkFrMOCZhANe@yC8EJr30gaWIqDp1kr2xqOQBbGBXLTS8tRC6bSKH2QEEBWVqKyEQEmG@A2eIf1JPKm/WVVK/N2rea0vCKGwVa6P4TdGpggOqVgtAJUpC9YWetm6yZbAJVGSBeBJJi8Q5McPsOxwGbASNKsKcr5IXKIWuB8KdIKwtHrGc7mApVSCrl8SS0WFBDLQEwDnlXCOTdpbEx7I2nqSgBPcgc0bxBrhQO/ZzgDeScwhJkFvu8GFFVvvmi1nDYw6K2blDdcf24u2k21na6xy1F2gvDpGrTeleJh2w0doO2SEZomvdkGetY3LpOzvkG9q8@U6XgSjDnShD3cB0bqjQv0um/G@x5GUOKeys5KWAUDv1PWTAjZGFXAB2JKgQ4FIy00PQXzJQHTi@whtBygW7EIbDmbETFMi@kI6IfOUgdkSl/mcNFZD6jGalZwUlieLIDkUSAk2pKOGQo9KMEJh4BZSYIIhBwP@id5FvhWkxgpQ7kfu57lJn1apkHWCids/QnUI81393Cg8HGKcgoDdNT5cKCA9oXjBDs1kziVb/h8whQiBdsNwvggLkYQaGEgmhR3og0W0A4pFs0QAPGCpo0zt6PlRCfOO0BjhwQpTzj/AUyMQwsYQygkROYF2ecF4SmRy2qRjh331EFoXZOVpa415esN7szDZXerHy8bBNc1HgagUeFiQwutz3fNHp/o5ZGpFCCHGmxsjl2czQAGj6iRSUUw@No@iqM@TppDz85JuGgJ8CV26wAIac/kU1bSGOU4aNWHLDn1lH3pa4ohvYEOdQV7h4WPVXFQ6UchAlZ3WtBETTAJSwySO6ZAn9KUD3reDjnuoGlhyxKNujsxnYtiJxdKU@ka7YhIJvk61Flya2srWU02klkw7YFpF017aMqAaY9MEpkwnIwmipElE/o2KQa6tZPnzRDyPN3GNjBH5uWNNUkZzWpVb2eNphq8NXynoSoA8xBawhfASabrdTSm02LjFJeNQISIlf0A286znmdNAhR8DDwJt8e7lxh0L8@soXh8NUbGdQ/kVhO53JSXbDVzrXbrrNXPtM6TWYydrhl1EFGBfk5TY3noubMJ8I7NfFUC8ppu6tV2rVtP5pI7qVRZsiEhI52@UU5nDI7rVNKENpVqtZKA0gA7zd7II3jzrJZOR4iCfAwsEHRsO5WUz8qQfjfdTmeSEDedzMLIUE8mAS@05ulToXFSgjeiu9YcUAkdE0bZ@LIG0WhaH8Pu@jVzMlp48QDRxB8w@jiJv9w2g7uLcCCJE@o3PH6cp1yZbAhZbx4O@GucP0SWbbLgA4zAc9pSVjZphUP/iTQYu1ND@UQGuU2OjdjJraQiSTAYkw@HRMV@aPnYhQ3HdGd@fLJz7Rwspg6uR6MZEMtwp1wWWpU1EczeyGXJ7VsAnUVLTkj4cfVM4mtwIYB@T4YbiSgyRrheAwwO7W2ygC7SrjCaGFIpE5z0hMsDheLktRylVqM4LIcJWUPH9UwJUAIxBNrIRdsDhUa4NH6fJt8uDT@BL42qOJRZJlDEu7ZrEG45uY4tSU3GsfjOEKM8NfuCDfRjAORR5nXhmX1lR6CFYtcbwQgBpUFKrEW1NQ48FNef9OXpHKIKKRzz455cwAS@95T1NU0r9gqDauiHrQKQPYJKQsHYASk79JJU8EwHlXzIZ6bCaYJHj@8c8ukbGu9xhMepvM7Y7c@AtQ1Et6emM8yyQ2hPluOOLUBDGP/Nsf3Udad8ogEsmyaHuNxujWe2QdNOF2eGrozXc7uuTbNRV0Vdhp95vmEbfB4s9N3/5CGIG8@PntXlaiyQYpyMr0wbp0LXJ8vxeT@@7ElLvuEKlc8bprhdEHHcCjegIpkJPIroMQu2n0Idhe4ldA@7FC7jBO5ldB/j1lNg14OJDLJGjkHACgXE7ai49y5wPFNz5@i@UQyMwqkUjvOuy9yeqRq5n0wHgxVnnZyPJSRN9tI5T858W@qKmBrPUoEHwj2qK2HigIoUJtqqujFcicLxDTZytLj5MNoHMTLtcHXzKXAsuIIHg76NfBXITSgl8O2kJjD5E1yoIdKNy3@sB3ywf4mLhc42kXhoIbFFHQgGNwVZGmFbYcH0e426kOMGy6Y@J6uul@UzO7sNvtCOYp3HJUqFLwxsdwDEbqMW7vnbFAxTSiajYASV8gYxqJi0t@BSUaOdIj7N9wsUpSb4Ckg0cy0ntealw/bbpOITGgZMbLXmN3LaZyAa4cbN7ZvK0KzRNqsN@KqFPsmAh@0umAQcH4bic@e9EdAZlpmvohLqZ@YMXLsv8YU6aDCMi3hYQcE@iWhDabBv2LS8cC8pbeblUZG@xrahXoJ7oUoblwPENq5GgKD7nLG3x9mTt6wJQ96J7E9sa9pm5/LU7YyCzVrOxS2unAf1PGPhC8E2mzrbf/rRJ81cm0MQxgYuvpV5Lc7DndLAOAOjhFvawYSbhabWlDgB2gxhYXlVGTI1p3UayD7A4AnUWJRQUCLM@lvz7bIsAxOE5ZSJOfcX4ywz0@fywDamU9PhbY6vgG5GN1@qCpKpU/J7wbpHleVocQg4Uwv9IIs19uzozuHTpzK0XD@VPMRFpCp0R6M3AgZlU6FDTMYLX2U3@kl2A@OkceZAgK4G0kcniA@NugaNHuQPSB1px9D0UuCYxvWfHjjTkhtF5BxagCDc8tWbEo4iYCkzDWUiYNW1@X/ucFEryGcVWnyGMAnoTt2sAm6ttDxzrNeyDwMN8a0QJBBWYbyob6eIim2r6WBP3xhXr0HCIqYRStBsMukNUDkILLJ2u8a3IUBYFMC8IWJXFKkqaEN9XQ2rvg7OwNIQhCB6/R170cxJlXZmex0o2t8W7IXn5Y/BRQiroH1zbbLbKervlzoyzwNfjuSU@zmJ0xcOglTZNjeIfNqbgod7tojo0Bav1a1aqxvBoJMhKaHZICxISBISwUmFoM2SP1F@kHkwGjmk0uwsQrqGKGdv3xIO2bbGCIdgUhmvjPNQ@gTC9MCF0jwITinEuQPqrcFeFuyzLUEMxazVxWL04Sy8cnKBO5VOxHg8zh1azrFLS06RqZOT1QJyhFHs8bF9OSbug6XHStAoDzystil3/rg7oMeaALTyEqzpkwPN6Qe8MDCRhvKUXjS9vybl1X0sK8kGO2RppAUzk15fE1KqlCnwoNu1NgUFJODWtPC9JhgQKWzPmpyX1fDYA07FwHgEhItLL8uiX9wCxVbwHmzlDd7/9et9wP/l2hnBQIGTn5GhA0M31pQ02FhZQVS00GN9xfI5@pltGYQYMl0Hsmd4UCTDjgzrQdM@AEmC4X@MqxpBjUPbxAdwjVc0M55zvigZvtcnsm5dzwGS2dsU9sKWMJ4UrUCBYNcnJHAmyDIpEpEuXgnmnK8CxURsJGPXZyrct8WoMfN6H82mM/4ExvXaSrQmeF/VN4OQuYLRVU2Fb56/oso943jWd6XJ8TDiU4trwi5LT8vQErADwYp0B43ri88LyDejh@9NwZZDm3JKr@tahe/M/InUJSm8z23UEcZXpODZ/LkpiBWcI4wMm7Fm2fT4wJYYQIeGEmzIUHC7qxRDmnUBzbbRXSAPMvrirSza3AAUp97LZHL6htXtyWRzfJQkKX6lsj72XO5xfKybI1D4llqJz6JRgYNNttfUKgxX1tiwJa0fM24k5uv2RlwKGi2rUhw8/0GHQK5s5Dgg9Wa24S1NVzTxZT7CZYRNM9LBsPHE6rnADkyYWpJVLRw6YgMGkcxwd94yIdzRTI/YDgxrHRrDEy1SZFpPAtzeFHetbmhTH0DQ@G5R3JMbaySyuwlTPfcU743swwhEU/5cP6K9WZurDyBOkt2zDRjHNw4HK5ODOPl4TUM9tXyTHusRe7w2o9OevdZ9tQuE037xabzrmrVv2a7PntHzKgQNPcACf65v0HFcWoYj0WR43HwFDQq3WSwr1LCHrl0sDxUDHhtrfeYNkO4H7w@lcBGFUtVrKFTI/riOGrw30vVjxTu@roLozKSHW2xjxiuG2HVkKlh72Vw6EAxw4W59ye7myhRTVvhU34aEccnl1FiE759h6NiE2nDomCyInQbuDiNUymCYepzF/llSy1@dWv/DiNIlsKXrChGr3GPbhMGKnpeqlGk59QvGUHO5DydRA3tmzsy1gsbj7isTT/hfIWR8eKZyQTG2g5l6XBzA0zFRqDeBZPhBucZxGm1XEhPDtnrm9azMKlGbAPc9QdH5CRieoOFyjKEzm6zU6op05jy9GmWjSdil3f5K7tDni9Kh8jWc0gp/7pt0XykxcQkP96jVC7lcLmBgYisuK5arJCk9ivvK4s@VhMllmfIyLK6yeTHj@jQILfFdkBtJkLZJsKfAlYriWI45XeDzA6lp13XtL1JTQFTxzLIL0qpEu32vqrFL7E5wjoUtpy58nPDoDjZNWvDRJpAtAT8oNF9V6fEloQ@qTQkXPce4ILVqvXr6JrbAdF0qeL4W54T4/l97My8ZzIaoclkuXdnrOIfqdk3b4K95MX8VvIqsXwlvlWgEi7W4uMuXdJdL8YkLRGmyAGRZfZBSRubYJOsVXL7RR20dwWtjoLmL9ybvuWn2lPmh2dsUYGIBXXDwubKGHGOWpq4D8tUUtxqinGLjZtbAdRMFDlf91iL5/tgYmlx9zFWUcjlhgbtpuFi3NK6fuqjyHTQ9iLbUC7K5SUCnOjYXfvheC/Dhogf1OhtfP912ofP3cA70A3r7pl20l4dYZ@SOnJE54lvXI9umzgHtccrV/VyVdcj1cIS76SaTlV32cXzarm1/CD6RNHJC6bqDtXk6xPO3eHjsC8Hlh/2D17WTd8aU0w40bOw1I3MG45LvTt2JKZFtU1AbJ3r4cxMNDRepf9YZpCvlfMBI@P5Z4V8rWw4NdzqZ0KszsWc@PSiqRMemr@ObBnxrCu3LdL2h/MYdd@XAUQ72rdAS@HoS07WmvRGeW@ct2xy63d7Iui7Tga4MJZzy4dYPkl0RMxaT7qCzbFuAXm8hY3upx/2f4ev@pkoPZo/4sBYZruBX1s3Q0clwaWIc93w@G4omVsUJ4Vhv5OfHq3QCv/p6Zk2XQGN7maLpXb4sgYZNeQ92T2zkrOiYxpIMB7sqNrZSYtKRIZfMHDA86qZkV/e5xbqYrvPHpgzFS0k5iu1L@SLoDvb@0OygFZu3BfeV9rWyaWntIOeMZkP/MsHk0/V9YNHwsXnagrZTx6asYcwynOC1Cc2areA5S3h3gOeamVeuqRSuXFShcKotGa4Frw68oOpmG@fQbGvi8yeTBhuX4oK9TCCLX1wv5LhZrBemg4rpmwO@BIKm61jEsevhTmTgQaQerqTjDDoSc854ccLluEMg6pLNloHDsJvYlrXbhNZXfzRmSp89MocG7rV@YE1xs@aaVkFNdt32omthf3Vm@NZXZ1CyTY0NlUbwZUgvrl0AbWvgPTSGVu/eSkVEmQwQHOz05K@V5o9Ol@vidGT5uKMpMlwxMYVNjjdibHUdkBvWhLw4bx/py1h2IH4Sc23odXPr7mSBB9YWZLpqWt2a0ixr8N4kOm7aBHZlJk5n48nMD17r80B7puKz0ONjcvdPLQAuvQbSykaGPV0/Ux2bcgUuLBgUl8ZN3PjXLNsdsq@VcwyYNmDCkDlf03Buw/D8BDfkeM6alkhpf@CyJ050SB4v2GuoWxPPVTjW9OrZnOkUN@eEbywMHznwhILyAJ/yrS8KQTpaj5EH1/P6y9PR14zv0PKeuTOvZ6IxUnkSFwuCVM2DcPcxnuhwUWXLaVxK67k2dC8w2Gu7TM91ZlPJmzlXjgrFK0eFKiq8ijUDlvrq4cPn6XhroN3a13GhoUq0pWnjhoELjcxygBHbTEdXQ4eyxB2uqukpbRW@Js4@6pPqEbm@466Td54sYAD5YIEJiP9sfMfs4bLhtWk/ch@6jguj0QQI5fipydUOrGz0WB8Roz3Ag/WAn/61yTwjsBsGIc5tGBOzC/VrL00fMhZxwHeMqbFhKKK5QZL/ItO1bcWyu6b3iib9YuZNIu1qhu6Zc5ItNjcY3gelaa/HWWKcj1vpIysrNv7EdR3@JGqbg5f68GqqAkMBPT58oVzGjfgr8wJr5bPVoj4@4btEzD7Xi7GprJ7ZdW3@vGJPkmPxPQGGZ5m@8gDVLJBbMc8k4L78K2lI6UoashSNgJM9MXxapF8vaixBqvMvsAVoZHg9F1fCAsMVu3NiuhGuIdPR3n6@caALiJ8DxTJ6s0Bf6XXZssfdMT02Cgyx2nxqdvFUUJcUikyN@eXK5DNDgTaF2I6uSAdBSK6wUxdZ6glII@nrh60VOWoVq9aEHkSpNy6X02YdybHM3hsDZ81cwtdybnrFH8qsPCLjhrnqWDeiWWTFoMP2a3vS6tY1YGhsU5qOPJD5lelV09uhppc16yGzsYmLzKurMBtZV9cfUWHd9evpEXH1TClQNwi0JFI9yPlDaX8j54ng4f/49scKDMKdYj7UfgKk6/oVfMj8zHOC14e0wCeuPx1Y88eQbzwFsImcYLEKEAVevGegaWdTIaD2nJnNZx@GsX1X4z6JYxIphJYkm8j11JRM50QiXXTzyyVy@aEvZR8VCE/NvhSoYsCVBulBeP4rCha81yygxmkjbvZUFY7YeTEfbP9ch9zTkDIAv@VOpYlPb2XiP7n/4PGRPPHVtePT/ghPR1zi41Z0O2jlXGxK6pXhxdY7@Xa0vuVPldvPVOngwX0ZA2zAN1/RkOCFK3Mrr43znqEiWcXYKAWhrzldzyDeO3r4ILM8oslSByPPHZvpuPfBs2dZPGny8bO13vHYd6F3DNz5xuj3D1U1vab5PndodXAT9VyT0iZIRyZIo9AY73HVMNcyVz13YvaPFhPzExg8kYL7H5h8cWMhHxkn1hB7IatsRBR1VFaRi/l0bGc2CNumF7031eexNUFq2aOXwl8bt6Mg56Arnr6ee7hqxf8iF8NywU6ELxZJzV1urXFVxorh/10zpqrqJjw/MwZQr6ywsbJWA6xbH7bdkw9YSjYD4UWKnKQptCrJunYfeUkaA@lW8IHT84EjGLsbt8FcBSByLq7t8KemszAcidayrmIvqhAbN7VdGeRr5gcsSEU7fE5QX/raNb5oSz1L9ciYvibhIy8W5eDg9v3rIjwNcHl1qI8ePWdPDB/1oFwdMJ5j8wNyvOSMXkk4b4VK@DYup/Y9AKVdCW84Wd@fq@yZ4fVdZzG/fhGOzqDi0E76jSNYaKNApm3NrXVjVY/Paz1Zv83ourT5IQ53scIHx/XjBIDef@tfqGouR9qP8K3muPWamgk7OEuhyVigSr2419H9iDT0kG@RwSG9Vhp9YM5xOwqfDV4n1K8d34pXjH2l9Obh5Cq/8hV@@SvSu@SHjkyXc@oVAAtX@LGCHHk/cO3TkSsfGJ7pr9l/vDZDVxWkckVBKjHqHChsp4XFwLyZxcejC8FrbWs9MqdefjJyu1Z@bRn2B6jnkj1Efe2X/YPtFIZH21uGbnDkg9vXp3c6M9cm9NB4s96DKM3xWi8gguZoRkciLnuvLpB2gec1naHFVTyy2@70kGxXCGbRief1exGsyZ3ZZHOOgTbiVzEukvOVgJ@CzOye@uw2Ho1bsulrZH/cH7fefRNPy6KJQdR0eu9oP2xdj58pWizFZS4@e7LijIdHp4@fxdw8cz7fJPRK800y5FqfZaqPjvIrye42XpysQdbm80bAbgA9jt4b@SBO7D5@dpkkoPg2mo7t0Odjw1nOmK5UWN@d0knDtZ5PFnPaRrm2pkd8F9s6P6@3xnlFsIcB2bIgbV/pdFAdU6ezqVUemZ/R2gOwQWzK2RIONFC8ZM7zozCHFGVjR3WPl8zPSnafTUaWM1/rNd4Uh3aRpl7567vBPntmu6fsQaRVaBN50NYDN05MZxNxWndYUaroV3Nh@gWWalO98A@oBK9NVXJ7E6N2gWbghoirqAnGf9pT7oaWT7T0teE/fhYGvz7sge3i/H3fmo2vD0xgM5nrA3pXkL@LAK3rg@H3Ro5HrudcHzRsTtXqbfMDM7H1wSHHi577AXnoDgbXBzr03esDPZzZUwtllvVBH7kzGzUIrPM79IZr3Ru7jVZLrsqbPFGhuz/y0pv9cV@kO/NBBrIi4hlFlF5Z0xXHsM3E3VC/vOnIjpu@APdjl30FNcmvQcWbD6yjj@9uCre6YDPDJX46Ebw0btrUO1no13byN9aQLB/S6RxrfGXYpcq/@57rcFt60/C4VP@3JqV7hm1dS9DCDQ/aNVsfcEDj/uxEv55qAYNwd3OdfbKYL8XN1dLbXOnEOr8DDZAy7PXS4UeQcGu6qscm/fj@M9PfPO1Ho/9XD8dGzw8bGjrx7QXowNUPwOgV/3qGnw2Uj3F1HVxJgi@HnzhJpRxo5OnV78nFNT6gjvnUNupY3ibtDhD27Vu2FWhUAA8x1NEQ6JBAVayWMzNRCQT/ytS0vg3J1OtqocL28ANuVabmKE38NmWFa7wME2uy7bNAP0K1qp6zrToTqyILNFRECuy5EnYAjOqjoVBMOlbZ9hR8tkPtCoy@J8TeMpoUlnqopRdsshLXM1ML9E9AnrbPntx/cvjsaP/o@bNmrn0e6KcIS@E4kFqoBeeG3heh8AHeQNjkn2QgvSg2JEffOsLJZD8sF8Pvp60Wrb5StGWhxD2Ms33mOIpCKjoU6RzyJ4k8NfJFlgmcOOywxFRBgXaWKteWQUo/oI44aJHShEqrsty6hCcGCE7bTuB/8XOD5Iufpazihykx4UCLPrT4oev2gxR9k11/hSne3b//4PnTQxZmcNlqTq3@dFSvFPhHFrjaIKingUV7lussGURJQl3V68m7SUBMUk6yKilVoQ8cQEOHYCF2UB1LEHuHpbYJPmAwGVWK8l@/rpwnZTx@k4awyTBTSUgW2jw1lK2tLXYEjYTdeXr/k8OnDPN/eIecEUUIgh2hRoc//VGffyIo1LgWfpLTG5OUQxqrhLhWl1DVyVIbC@Kc@u5k84c56ZM8pPMk@hZQ9DEzQaBPRUG7PSV9rRcUaaZJtx3/kGig5zRMiJpQ@FkRXOlFnaVIPy3fQo0rmIcBqhBdbey4OZQ098psH786it82Neh7VZD1mTPlavoCZV0JaGlyRHOybJsyy79uJcYCJne3oLF3TRCAme9YMARPq@wVtERcTa1yjTyS1EheihKCrpJJQqEpFvCSzlFfaXnK@1/5Z8qwxsA8BfO3A/M8dxtsvxTYBmD@ZW5@oWBDu6yjdJmXeIZQtXFQAp6RCP@I@9jHVh2uBWmJOFSlGhJWZo2hmk4I6xicp8CfEtDjJZxU8xOoNGhuUGOB9iOenum1U6hbuaoo2KRwUkYmTsKc843gF3QsFwvFvKpAJqWTECB9FGWIGi44wHS6Ct1EOLEm9Zcg6O/u7jIRZ2bNerHGa1bZdl7o4ssoo9sQVoCRGzLXZBAHoixjgF8jiAajT0ZNY1SkXkk1iYSr78KwRP44fKHdCRAhshQgi@PIxK9szPG7vFOQVwJd4V38km3sg1nbASBJhTGJTGlRCPQGPXKn0Hygky4/icf1BuFBCD4EogZcn3@tmlR0Y3uUL/espbqL8MtcQV@TkQZwUHru4mgar1vxUwTxDEFUxXXNt/mCtaYtp63wtsmgmf5gTWN2wPyLynBDm@Xl3r@sHTl1UbcxIovdeua4OAV9FwrDUpqi6YpaTC@LlM@vLVJQoiAZKA6qYHsLyQGZApLRM61X7sTfPzi8//HjJ88uaQCmkMmLwYDuN3YzLUnONtuRIRkv1mqV3L6rPHt4@25YEctMF2PUGAh/UBL1qpIsV5YQ5PKk4sWircvhxdJtzvGnXJfJxfzq2lVZo0iX8qHmvkC6dFpIuktnfi8mrpXXYatQuCpLS3hKDPQBV9hwKaup9Nl5sw3yn5NIXm4JazrCi4S8g50ATC1/Z1vBxn65cFiw6DvyR/hlTj/eF/X1fVHc1lHBJOqLmbrHSxWcgUPMI1beMBkgkYKshEE39r7HnElfKorV@HfuuWbKuN69WIaLuaswHgNFRQUex0MqslRzHWh4HoFsZltdIdR3yDU9hwppIyXPXFdhKi0E32viCaf4IRw2r85l2hqcSiO1I1hZdpXS6BBeWoAOjdzdkxnIiE/cCf9@B20Bu2OGpqcukN87Mz5lbLKPZ2MIN6DXU5OW44FySxAZMJmMssp5KaASgc7oeQa1ckN6TdQcHRRcHvcLqXlaHpnzvjUE2p5KZ4Gi3VDVNov0SmOhSY@0kxSpzpa1cGVX/AjVcMTR/oWUi8@XGTCahmw5fXOeSp4m09U2pI/uydNPT5JpcV1bIiXngdbv/kVt51H2S@rVlMSYBr0zVCW@jlpUKpepBLhdBMy1boYfD6xU5JEv0Mdg68i5P5t6D8AIbERqMDYmLDVzuMZSmZE11Uo5WVLlKDW4NmSHZTIkUMGLPGRGMQdk4uN3ynAWLKXU8XvB4Oo7fXy9sSasqcpyG8yUSJpt40c9D4DjQh2@aQGEYIhSJbB1bEIgZkCOeCeReQOHOOgPYeFFel/XeNM3DmnV0kWcUKlZ4yaLfaR1lXMUK5VqUKGrVLHCoPVdJoeyAmAv0bmQrwfsBsrMAGcg/spCYknIL1O8BKWb4Bm5F2hBg@wkYhrMQ@VoDGAt9Yv3Rh7eqUMH@grwB9Xq86O7nXJaEVmkTW3oWX1cVeffAYlEvODLbdBNlZWgyRqX6D7CaKi3tsPVtaH61LvUYcQLJDURR0Og@zsUlv1l21TVK1t9EDGoBQiZxwEgOHXeCcGhruFwdmqN33pi/9OfJpDZSG2r6nHHO8kkC7kaPNRagRXYje2WJG03c/Vb2wZIUdPX8xbI5MpO/sS8Mxr07w@VligyneUVZefs7Cx5d@eJ9aLAilLf0oqv54tzvai/np/ravn18UQtNuXX87ZYrmeP261mmz158tm7zru0OD9ZvBZZKwWy5sFjUc2LiWqFne0V9cRxBb9mDuLNMXsD1/GA4Z/Mb/oxs4Hm7gBE2KTIEq0WYFwVS6KiNJNt@JO4/xIuLvg3G3JD3mu/e5duGsZ0vmCWZU38fh9udwQcpJZ@xkBevgmUnkdQWIveJEHBVRjPgdjtm8Ph7NBYWLO701tySS7LWmx2Yffh1z4Nrtqnz58z9pw9f/7m6Ya5iHYmk5KkJpnnF/yqHaOQwO@R/@mPt86zZ086u3/6jbFibuHrMb6@ff4Qzc/Uwo2trRu3b@fzWU3TuPnJ1578/P7@fv5OtvCkWdjLS7mt3T/5460tTdvVlK2276vtZPP4@DNRy@VF@U9/mOw8efJV32/o/8fX3zVUfJTgccJKQCfg0pkKRnyW4VaRx/rQK/EmAa1cTSzo10mE7mdbTG3slf7bdx@/TkwTDU351IP3NPE6USwnuBEMYNND20mikdjFYMXzxEKp1@tgLP23fw/xGx8DHPRZ7MKjUQhhFReJhlSnKG8TjSIYVE2DdP@vr389lkNOJurExoXXLdaES8yXNHGvDdcOXbsCaqmVcooShnOmo6npMrV8U72JFgss8HJM/NyHOW0l1HKePb4FIZ82M5lMW@5IcMkvaJJIUVWtpao3gRxIN3bqdWmHcT28ul64id8SSNOU1tCFEdO8@enKlfj07@VaC6b29wD4qZAobt16eafRgNLpDX2nkaEr6FLUu0pl0XVviSzLXiZBGGm2X7LaA/RqiLmyJmaz2Vsd3jXmiDVpHnaRBF78mUhELth52QW3Bvb7NovceSx2OS6Lg14bLnGI15/9r3/2vT/7Lv2@R/d/QoW@Tt8aKDsQ6AQ6RwOuW9Vqr9EQG5541kJ7A1pUrlqulpXOeSu102y0nzI199HbZEFPPmM4DqiYRivdalL8BiXbCJJHeyOxdG5wl0bcLfDggckB3gGmWGIVa2SOsMbYhXAwyAZHH6TmSaMtIWtUl5pqsdCWeKzmLagcUStVxE47IW0vgO5o7YZW0B6zWw1@sdG2z1zMja4Vw4IE@W0sy7b0WdoacadEI4zWWIb5ouGCPFWERLOptE0aGRphRm9tVbfK1WJVUzqNzVdtGQMvCmqa5hM/cZKIrhoL2mGIz0TUMmNuL@I1EVULCxswW4l7TTioKyAR0DP4P35p0cWouvSiKtYCk9YRWQ3ah6ZL2rAj5lQx6mw00Q/XFvzoD1dkxecWuQTOFOTytcWq6o6mK4UbxUMNB9prrni@BRgwWK/b7b7pdYH9MIyu0TPUqTEz5sbCmHZn3Xl32pv1GO8zbFl6T3cLbtkNrbKU0AvqduImFknXKloZvwWpl8t6RdNLql4q6qWcVi7o5YpeyuulEgDUS5peqeQ1TS@W9GJZLxb1YgXcNQhThDA6QigV9IouJN41t9hTTtbaLBNercy113NZ7gRGMrh4S5I7TwiJf4CroWoq24GhLwcP4PfICOI4/lRVYAng4c7a73aa73agxzcyu0Rt2w0pyCW85M6tdkY6P2@CuVYL/ruNyFiji5ugcO3zTGb3RQNYmxeNZgZAvghAyhIjoHKnwdq75BWlFiQX@O@2gTuSMrvN3bp7QLdMfU5qA8jdlWzeupWRwXQLYja2oW@nM5ltSdrCAbcZDDsQuN3IhOUBSO0US@bdZNG9xaDwP@MNQiTQj/Pd88Z5c/f8fHcX/rv0PA/e4Hq@e@lPr@W1IczSv420p9VUGi2lFdCfNthlpYEustICQwPeEK6pa@U2jnjIv8jtf5x/Obt8Ri6Y5bYMuRYSO2wngQpr9cSOkHj5/vP/Ge/W@89/D3lRBj@zKiTOkFIoOyjJVrhACw/mPHTYQ345YMY7tKILOjQeoqPDHw4udinKS5lV@XpCSi0X0zIO6R130EEdODJ7CUFXSCtSUSZq5aLYyagLjSV2xWKJSOjPXbqSyeQ/ealVSkk@CYRKXF76vv8wlstlPiFwTcupkvq2wb9Twj8p9XPrrn/yc5suIfG2wswq4CfFOGKEBLSjhKJIUkNINHbHeMoHl2EklHhP6p9Jz/clnKIxprTI1uPTD/X7h/VKpYHyj7n9hPrOzp0deKrwP9yCUrDWAIK2BvXeGHjr1kAvaC38pkVC6r7G34M3@GNHPfw9fY0/dvQGf0@n@GMPu/g7eo2//S7@jsb4u/0afw/f4O/5EH@tL@m6WhO3zwgxGbWinm/PRUJQDUasRutLU29RpQ@0idqeBgJrMImV0vOVdKL1JXPeMyfTajDbiEeuzN60ZtQrtW5dC4IG@8XRR7Z83HyPy1DB5GJVY2mcBtUrBdeTcHMjPMAho1dU10v@5Dvf@EayXk9KSfq2Vh7cpC4G6lIgsELMPM8JfrMY8gfV7fvJ2q3kl5o0wVCotJvo2QYPIVFn2@q2mrNzvZzaVbtgsFjOY7lRbqT2VRLEcibLLXILlhu7ah9MJvxyYLJyA5YbspyTcyAY@IJp2slN0TSA1xB@AwDkwc/CffNdNddjkJCNrCh9RljtYMzc205LaLIkE1@aIEnLqpyTi1Ybv3zWFF@@bCk7ba1SZjI2a7nTfNlKtsWWiF/D0Cp51l2YW62XIjAcOZE3f3RhCd8H8byWUFothSMe0EU1eX7e6Rw@utPpKDgStpjZyNzKAIG/dasOBD947SUatb1WlcaLcMxIKLt7rYYuobmYgdFAQ7fMF7yWEOHd2KKSt1@evgSBJnWKYs3pCbxOQ8OnLXh0uMBD3srpp62YlQyKcnrKQ6@BsGJYMjLxP8iD/1B/6x/X/@FzlmapZjudOjvfTdGVxl86fXZ@dh48G@lUKrCkduGHDmDHKGfnDTRSoDMwNVPpdvr8nLvBM5Xe5QAbkMxug@Iuw52xRJQipcofqb/fN6QcXK1kjc3rJO/nc3pte/72LRf@CznqCgkgTdG2n1ZrnsulgVAFX@rBRWzjLe2tSNfoM63b3aba/pMf0teY9tIUqJCv1dQdxi1aXqvV8qGtVK7VyqFlO5WqXL4auT21CFJRPp9O12pg2QvB5sAKcZvsXYbVWQue7Zs3eSJlLSgFwNTzxUwOt1vVamFKBUjW9I1eQLXP7j@mDxkBrSgkGJKEYNdJKkcfQkNanhSr4s2bqb6J5yv6e/vpmze1Su7t28hlMgEndcWp0@lbXqeD7vrbt2JHpI06lQLYc@W3b9VcJaMm066XeoRfaYWkUpLKbmgNSrUCdFrLl8A7yEBhd7eYbzSKeXAplpNQhzVOpGtJMVkTE2dUBLVc4hRMJOcEdGgYH/2z8wTVIcsX0ikgfmngHM8T@POQTvLxqVBI1/K5XOLsXOSB1UqFh06zfDFVzlSCX30rzRrAHfEfsnh6Jr9T2rkFzDL@/Pm6C0lp7cysq@f1M7OKU/3nNRjhfRd4G1QBZN68qVcALeVcrSUE9LcOIxAyWPBoCclkht24KaBeJC9Zrd2iulTLBZZI1rijlAQ6zsqAV0XbKahlRIVgDVChFzAJAhfUttiWoNEbH0KF81Jb6AiCzyXKJ/ThYn3WZUO82BDlSGYxmy5mM@5Pz14vCuTyK/CNrBSXRM3QxYwuIeh4Om@XMPQ@ebB/cHiU1XYlltDu7h9ktWfPbydUtBaWdvLW0f70cP/O4@cQ4cmDw/1nhx/d/@Tw@RNw99np8oqGhXBwiAaJmGmN/ZR9Krzy3himaZgz0@yczmanr9kry@pYUJf2DArlDj3mmx0oy8RYlqsGd8/yjVevDG9CF3v/g2@9/8F/9/63v/P@t7/1/re/95PPv/ctuH8E93f4@zv/rlLA508@/xe/8/63fhsc/xPcfwj3j3/y@a9/nd9k/yO4/0vM7Y@COxaO3wLA@qWffP7dH/7k81/@Ptz/Kri/f/n@lR@vv7/3zc03xvvu71wd5jv/Hu7f5bDCsN/5Le6G70vhf4uH@@Xvv/@1/8D/fxL80Pjb73/tj/ARWP759//kv7z/xn/UtPKf/Nv33/zu@29@4/03v/3@m/9Ue//r/1bNxR@/8/57v/@Xf/C7f/kH/yP9f0TP3/2Q//vv//M//1/@/H/78z8I7h/D/R/A9OM//4/QT//m93@A/@/@/t/84Q/w/z/967/5/V/9m1/6N2T4DW74v//Vv@PPv/qV//zXv/ntv/zx1//6V3/817/x@3/5v//y//nr//mv/vvf@6t/9g10/I0f/@Uf/tJffONbf/HNf/kX3/h8w/NbVz4//wD3z/8BXD48nx8C50PK9UVdPv@Z8vN3wcYyFWgn0Lp/8f2v/wI08F9j7P23foRnZ@He8P@RplKYH3Hb/w8M2uUyo08OTHD/6vtvfQdR9D8AiuAf4evbkWXFh1u@vbQAWn9zTaRf/Mnn//KHZEuY1QatJOHQXdbKmR0Qb3YqlWD4DhaZIMovrEKLAAQpfRsp1Irft5G2vf/B19//8J@@/8FvvP/BL@HgLeUr2f2spF6zQgcBCx8QDgMWPyQcBvwM0u9kaIZOynwGtq3PCmXdcZzaZ599JnTeKnhI@9Zb9hn82GfhxbgXHuIOvEI/dMdT3Qzcmy9ftnFZN@amqBy4ovF34IW77iElSbuR2VNUjXuZb5VtHovVwEEv661Y1pXBYKcKPwaPanXnLCvttYDto6jnghkWSQ2gbilMNbL6jm5AQCXPw7GqcyuXz5R2DAPk2AzCzRAPtBNyZAWdzTNBkvNg6RfdIdB8h4xzxufz5@Q9F@a0Qgz/EmNlpjPm8H9NYBlil@jCj9mGRjIE8cLVZTIKBUgms1wtIBaRcS5th7vQmjmlm68wLMF8npmD7A0GSCEDXreB96/XMxixzrMIVl6YRplRVjKZOpQbY/M42U4ZQcxvExSIWc88ZZ2d@pxHzCC8RoiOjIBOT0VVEzPl@h1IsD6/wxAWAiewL1/WG@X6vIHg3nHsZOaZ25QnBFbPzBvvwF4nmBBPSNx5B1kp1zOZRhkTxELy6sl2eCUVqHBU9gzLBHUAbzz6sHeLsRuiWhb5QskWIoyHxmdmGRoDQnDwb2V2guLQPzTSvUMI36KkglQY998jHnmPs80YAOBKkizLDG7ci7DHboH3nIPKULLwynAIGWoR1AIiB4azSRkhQ/WbIQukn6jvfOELgWFhtre3hURD1MXHMqFOUZh3XKVzILg1EgWbKhOLFRGdTToUE@YF4tco/e0kLi0mGQfMbmT4fevWDrsBxaT30k1gUkZ3826CQ9nNZEQN4DfcjPACpCEB2ikBeivI8zotZWaEbJYxuZ5AP/b48eMgE@Twoi5koJlruop2XFGbzWYJiCHLWTmbDd4yvclBDgwy@QZveRuRe@pZU5NpWr4GQluNoROLS1gqyNvo@O7dO6gV2mtWvQ9yLgu2nWn5MnmCA9eRZduL8PSUlq8IfBqAqcU8YymaEoYrzfCYUAoaUlrgZxR4NsIrldTK5SSFBPzLqZ1wH2JRRQrAz2PRkWlWKK1YITdxK87t8QlkXE@PDkLx/KXKhXToefCYHTx@@PDw0dGk3WYCfjB3NjU7E8/tmb6fQr/9R3f4cRatUkwnmk3EylFVQ4okHFZz2FAz9@88vf@syjiWgjpLUTlqtBQd4KWiConJ5NPdRLBtS8SvnrriM3xWl6hIaRWglulEQ0j0TBSBoPHhH@6a8NAf3nbnLJXLimJWLaJImsYlVcjHz7szhjq5uQIv6IR4yEXe3SUMCI0zKbaCgw4N9lQTuEFSycD0Sjk0lLhBLRUxAN8ayXSh8ezwCEAfPWaqlpOFxmdsLmPWpHOhYddt0xlOR9u4x1Bs5cRY6bebuSz@NF2Hp5ovZtVCqb21ZZ9JmFCL2sMZbhY9B@uZhAX@MlxM@LLAvgxOcEnnTMAtoCyYEb//uBZsgkRFmSm@E1JUC9CF0wLO6gfwhEn8gtaeuLAsJiS2vva1KWs0Dh/dke7fRdF@PmLhTkDJ6ssjmdpEf@aZ5DtkrG99YuG3b@W@5U9sYwEdExCSOD8/HwCk@3eZ1tDIymP08XneI5cumM/nhgDkbSAkboZTGELCqVbr79R8SXi6X62@0zVNAAdhR8Gth1vQemjfxo7CfzUfEtX1sgJ0URVFeOm6LlDbZ0LVFBht03mXq9cl3oL1vEq7dAT8vpIxry/X24Ow8xvLsHqOh0Uf8GDDqcdyoV@J@wW2osBDAhpxZyLuMhfCibHczZs6ztXo@VxUTEZIYOdQYdt6XsdKADdwbSfypWAdSRTFdkKwzSnr18GcaMGjxvuhmhAZ2pBO6eWckGgmoFcKzXaz/v/@r90U2vN/vH9AS7NZF@ZA3OJ34Ixh6M1WfoLw0H28/D9@PI5br/yPH7sPH7tjF/4wej1EylNb/mu1FevV/4DoIXGpwVgkTPF0Ug5@@VxB@P/MBT2cmjZfydwNVHo3aJ9tU63k24fQdZqsvRtq@25A6F1@UJmhmrW6iAVXplZweLnhm/ZAxgN6dXF30tBzmrgbfFekEUZs9Ot9tzfDHVG1vmw5junhsWgeIZ8Xa66DGnrr4XIhjDnpM2FYPyXVLYJZH8qo9M1zDFvoy123v5D96cLGo26269WTIKckQ48ldBMYWJyr3dP1fBWKJE/cyZ6gFUqZppoDzgNvtZzVslvmXqlU7cs92zS8vUK1UM728RRdsJi7V8hVh/JnDx/cm04nT006WreXr0AEVJOKCg33ytVCAVquKGaalEy7mWvLfPCRtraAXJtGX4I3rvX6klZuQ@S@5dXryeSermqSWtVz5XNhiTjA@Uht5HP5XQXeIFQpuIYMAyPgFJGs7ioTrD4wQhADjF0wFnaVLhgtMFZ2FQuMs4au5naVGa9FxFlDwMxkEFdZrMnsSD0LRoyq4zrmuVDNGlnrjFBbHQwG5ztnmaVFMM4kbgOkn0tGtnsWWWtSLFyVzbKStfQEF2MAdXgWLI1XRa1QFmvN2tJeKoq19rlwa2z2LQOP6bVyZ5djFWEc51ATkFCLCedVz3Wn1a45cD1zGVBXi2FAnqHLAfLieZRcK4cpnl1OrhgLND@7DCVfEM@jWGG2hPNzqEyOb@htL14IiZ2nn@iNBjSMs3xJyxfyBU0vFgslDXiPSr4Isn1OzRVzBU2DXpivlCulc@gFivIuQR/DZQdnYe@o0ueAUkaV67Nutln63SPLPivrEu/HqXQNhrPEOyFx4@knWqOxeZ4hBbzaJ5rUqOuFCph0NGk6DX6aJmm6pKuSquP/GoOG/w8Pr8FfwyfE0jXhCLXcPQIWCjhEhz1AbVlTlx25@L3EIbtt9jaEOBgZdIrgwHN9/@8Q5rbhHHOvOxZXLR953TPwo7H@2JqONoR4PhmjgjzT@weDcDjuQgaRevIAt@Hh2a67LkCJPX@yoZQPo4@5ADL411wg@NP7H907ir2PDvcP7glFdvvxozsXXoUgUIE9OLx7FFlL3DeMWohA/PzhgwcXrcEr//j508HM9fAW7j5@nl8@Iic8pC7k4VoNFDkTkOCBVpJHgJUEgb9QCg2qgEebbuYr7GZgLBSXxhwaP@Un8C0/OmrDlTFUhaPwWL5Bqjq6JutxPYg4K0Q6igOJUS1VBGHCHPeUlXKs79q24TF3MNgCx5GBR4xNlINsG1siJn3qenb/1OqbW8DbQBoVECcHlAnhHgAZz3qkYge4WNR4D4Ogw3CltWvPTDabsI2O8EInNHrWcARD9qkbBhC6hsHg/qIXxDfj1/RqhylPg9wu@diXgwsJoZIoi@KBKN4zpkbNM0svctXqEw@Gbn9oNg7n0Fyh8xjeIlvO6uJUvMuqzosdbYiLdrY7QanVnzR3ZsCib22B6P1Xv/mjv/3jX9VauYMczjY@fJDXFsBdqEqtW3/H1OK4@7bxgu3l3VuMIUePAqDcSaDeDZKAGEo4jISYQNCRSV7WKuVCuaJr5Wy5Us4X1GKhkFW1rFoqlyoAIqeW1WK5UFGz5XwF2Jp8BXwLILhyMUkJ5SJlpwpgnZ4965u7JHLLI5Ct@do7e5My0ixhRPYZE02IIwo4HTIlhQ47Vh0GT6bmmF5iANFgPZa4e/cgd/euKN5GC24/OsiJYh8thXIuV7otiib5HJSRRRNdHqeMmobFKbfkcrehEmYcAH6kRxRHaDks4oSyKFpoOdi/exfTGaBFw/gQ7Jj7cIsdWkoQzEELCG8E4HUEDYLt83TylNFDtGCS6HOX@xyAnyh@FGYHfZ7yYBzAvbCk@/uieJ9b9vfR54CKXeAZ/Qpa9ukSRQ8s0DlEcQiGoQfdUhS7YMQuIoo9MPUWBriNwYTfcXGmhiguOHoQQaI4p9BG71gUO6E7JvNJkJsCYrdKFpWX@hZZKvgTRS3MNAbTI4suivnIkoey3bv3iTGa9s0hvxYef/egpPfu6YY1nx3e7X70UXc47HqL/cOPnqLXwcE94EQWM6877AYRux24XIh1cE8zjseLixeU@n6nUzXstV5f6XTyhnPBq7PomJhDiPUachZcQ0xo3DkAr4N7nVvGun0UBLCD1GEM7y5et8fwvm10uVd4kRe9592uWMPmryitlIACCG6JwO54DNTWyY6NnufW0D6vs1wWmZpFs5hr18iDjUGQyNXO0X@QwqeBs5Dps0VzXs@16/N6Kdi4OEiJrblWsMTs1nhPrRSqW8aequUz8yrqlHEHSZaU1D2WUm/uvGGpR@k9DYSKLbG1tyeJTbW9Vyy9QAJUxceeppar@ZzG0tyql6oQJ5fMMYaPdLPU3isVqsvIpVLGULRqqQSMG@BnCsN/F@f9OiyVOjWN43Qas05zS1AeKjhbUKGt2iA1z87rPJNska7N62qNf8yA5S5AS6X6@OWcWQ8VpjMOdAgA53u5Km7BSYlqpSxCHhQllU5HNFAB03Km7tOvHh0fHX1GPGIjmPh64plIzGqB9aN7B/L9x6ENv3oj30Xe1fXkAyRiKz6ciQ2djkAike/BqAvyYuiGR3k915YPafspMMChR6h4Tw400MtH91bgPBu5pzxl1IRSIzXGTs9k@FEgq8@MegNMRp@lKFfMSJ/SeN9pNOqd@piUhUARw1hfYfTFnCWY@z7Pe6SfhaKf4fHWwKNTz53DmDNPzAFOp84k9eXY7b/UMr1aH78FdLt@GyPXOvDu1sy66XmuJ4KwJ9YGe0595vjGwHxieqh56P7jbeA@8MxrasDM9DZrHWLoAxRazqWGx5xlzh7NxilDanTTq044/xs5IHJSXw0LfUbHsDt1UTyvDeos9QKCvga7t81Sffl2ei9fAzzdZp00OOVeDl4OmMaK@RrJJimEBT2L8IPlNli63vgKvDjs42oVchNU9DFAxcQAsNUnDwg9sc5rvbrNUhKbszQhKV8b1psY/S0@diUY3CWp@bYtNCTpU6EB3be2SBh1f9alz8ixXFfVcsXaHNzUUr42guo1XsxrXn0y88yaDdZgMpifODdqgFTAHYB58zb1/he@nt6VCnXuViNQb5E16Mid@rzmoGJqaBh1vQ4emWY@ly2UgWsolLLAAmjFrFrM6tl8ViqhK4z/2UIWHEEoAoYkZadExsRsbp6T1axqqtlU7qXVf5nOHqeAzyGksXR26h46szEDF6gqbJtkhTegJ6Pt2CCs9V1m7ErUWIFq1LBggPURm1jZEYJ6aho2xUinJabvpOztFIbZPppNDpvtavVwPvkqeKWk13vFTCmXeZNO11Jb6bpvvhYaNaGBBIZKPdmClhvMkzN/Nm5CLYNJLWnVZrOLRSzlsnpOh9JZnbfDXbEhtrO5raIKVXRO00sq43QjPk@MDNDSbdJBZt02oerUilYTZJqz1cuaVFEKO4UcnzjmMYVJQOAQkyzVEkPtCqlksqQlk@lkDRfItsRggQNoGtGzJBDY5E11TwTeTKyKFQ0DLIkjHaDPhbkD7uxcQE6S5UEWPhPOz853QXj/kvAMz0Xvai/wV3rxcP8x/r4EThWwll88fP74@eO7AlNo7zPwkbWtmlzr1MAiyY1bQqLKGJDSVqD7Tdli7Ivuqs7sNl7wdwuP4wBcgb420WRt2u1oWijpsU9Qr8geS0IhDG/c1DS93dRKMBYCOQ2Dappag1x0EnjgR25AbczPIH@7mQYeyf0KWyyMjBROD9ysNoaZ7Zy2SJx0xGJF5ydKG2rumG0lb@4wYG8kljg53mpoO5nkk6qeSd5J6vnESaq13cioi6TCdjLaYoDbNHC5X0lCOM3cuaHvJJ9nquVhtqpm8KnBs5pk0lbiVid7K13xBaoTlrgwX7Ff3x8@3a@FtoNGWVsER4kTLzpiuRRksbUNKNMyL1ZjN2AAfoGLLbghM1lLJs6SLJE8T543k20hcYsOLGv8wDJLREeWcaNEsHyo54ssnaikA1upkvBT0drdl5K3EklcIqv6/rsEtarwFOhXXmrQoBOOGzqACIhzbzDgFgq4OJRQXk78r2ll/eH9x84d764pJFpbb7dcXNULZ53heud8/FXGJoDiJGvVE/N6Pjh1oTYakrqroYrGEqvCmDJQi1LubYP3mgZ5FDXwef8L38/Pd8tg13Iq2DWtkNEaDXUHmJXE5P3nv4fKts4OP9l/wJK4nPO3f/xDrfS3f/yvaV9n8pyWeDS9lICQaFSLpcTZ2eTs7Bwu7ldItBOXtrO0AT@KalRKOzKURikbYOgoCY5HYKpKajrhS4lgN2@xIKVSqqKld/RyLg0@bwNleiktVwZruERKTmKxIKYTh0@tgqbe2t2Dku3pea22BXWpRofPWfTbNf0KVE754cu3jIGl1@gPh5ZGJkVh1XfS7jsm7bJ3uDr5TtpiL@sN3I6j4pH1cEFuB4/C4pJ3spFRdpIMhDHWaJ7XztsZWtIjwfbFjtO6gIfWFp6zWnXaceBn7vj0M02ykoMP1tBm7rzyxdROWlH6fVLuiCumktRI8B7SMVmhAU1lR4Fc7oTrcfwnSa30@1/4dU0r/u0f/8rbztvOZxoIspVKUdUSP/3p7syZ@Wa/8VOIeIVqpVAYJRYUdSChIRJiGdeDagWxIoPcA/l55iDDzsOHIi0KsQy4G2vomH0SaYUT5MioRjtcu2c/RcF2UPNKlhh@0qaXrglCyAxzht4b9rIEg@2g2vZmOy2cCV9GLxjwGQgFNeHLS1DgMIYh3u11fHvmTeh8Woriqe0suwlRIIUvo@bULdIYE4wWElBNZedyVJ5ln7BG3Bsbm76PelhhoBO@DFGCb1vYCzYxULkRhrQcGJ5kDEL5JI9@E9JuQ9o2j9Ah1xSVngfIMp47HskBPl/4MjAshAUL@Bhm7UKAGpCTLwMCoAypALDVZrtMT7MzK5OpLZW8njOodDyvZYSKVQSMhtD6qMgnjFzDcOAE8gV@TR3bRVDDwEbGHEMgHAbfyFIHCQWjkw1ZQ9J89MGgABZpGUxR0djNm8tc1etWP82oRAj/2JrgdBzVg7M@rwAsFPVu9KtilqH63FroGjU7wHiGsgutTuJ6c2uxqExE67kgwP@DGy22yAtVRR41LEBQX7xX9ABlEBnRzuuwx3brTNVKaRZlvgd571GmSL1FJL@25jdk7bPQ8xxy@NNE@K1CIFZH8SnOoN1e1KzDgJ2f4YfiUL8iJwaBRhyuQRGJ3v1pGDuKBUWxbAo9sDwQpWiHTai8NaWraYy2VHZL@aBjKlqe4WmRQhpfFAtDM3gbqIQ0SGeLlKf1XKhQf@I6pLWUtKrhYR1oEUCjAoWPPNsz5xQ/LBrUDUWO58gnZY/Y8jHHpIXVRfVUFBd3rHQ9ELpD3GSZOZRZb9xnWoWlqKGRYkonApemSJThLnDkiOOubY4hS89Mk06J@lVFGQKTNuuSds6HFrSr0V0LRh7HV@5wBCun1rGlHKGGf8kd4GFSrusogXwddj@@5SXQhGm77jGzrWOTz1ynVjRF@QxkEmCrs4DZ5Q2IreI2LU3P4kyJmuWh4C7Bq8SN5Wws7lZqkb781tWtVAdr9C2NYBbUim2eGE4Mv3S9FQJh3F/4oa450pgGdjkiuWagZaqeRP0xkfo0IdCaVyeFbTKuiExSYkIMtc2hUZh45glDsVrAMQaIZi/U24S9GEr7ZRoAqO9Bz0IltFOvitrGICdeP9WDrhcQeIfdYLomYECuCjBQ2wcwsOrrq9DBD6JiOfxpHypGpmUApCvQO8d98EM9N0Hzw/hh60YzKQheNm@2FYDDQYfSqjPeLUJLIWbB3oHtmYq@BZ5FyOGanGylxAyAzYhpkYOO4l@Mzlu7QLSkyi5DyjKEEKAaoBCrYCDJQS2jsS@ACuBx2/D5Z6ICFbWnp6cy6U2eeZZs@vhVTN91DFuZDC3ghF1lao4niulD1/WsnjIJ4S5NEv8YrjwZTfbmyM/WKzcX/C0IA78e7F1LJQd@EgfHE/zo43BMOhZRuaFPDequRR@M7aWCrXS8/Wnt7FnY/qrY/qRy8hyBMIZg5tlFtpcFYNlu7zg7OO3XAo8T6pAAHGrRDB1Rm7kXWsZ@aLImgyiEO0U6Gnl17WNaMQZIIp9SXibNSxiGXITWwD6x5hDJMU/ZvucZixT5pzE0NuDUgtgetoBhn3zAiJ/QOOOqta15c9FeiT6PosOgFm3C8FCBonB2NVCuZx3959x/Dv5z7j9fJhom25y3OUuGTudYHGz1qHc3DIlgFmGYc66TfOlDkIEPZyoHgSEXK27ncPfqFDvEN7dBPdbDhgFtYgIIN1NK80Wr2Wo7vnm6084oQ2jsIiECahxAN9uE09N@ZEbs2yf2xPVXnBxUtwyjUpBvdOqNgtbA2wqWMaogahgcXxZqyB2Og90inCEICgwQkA8DT2QN9qcpK12LFPuTJzScprjEMc9YM8hMm7ivwCtwA3aJo54jNg6oHQOE7lGRIJvgw8Kew7@BHFKHTz0XwoRhJfps6xg1NSbbScDkha7CaU2NKimWK0kKswloR3a1frEooT9URfOCV6yY50H9x7O/9YWzP4B@sT731GD5gFET/p/uvm29jRxJ81p8CpiSS5lW8iTbsk2ZKlMSZbPLljySbLdXVrFSZFLKMk/FpA4s2/3N7sW@wO79PsK@yrzDXO1T9MYfAWQieZJc1TO931a3xcwEEAgEAoEAEIiwhwoMdUmF0MOFqaq2Kla/EgaFB34nGNLMVRP9VM/WVM2DgllmSD1oQnQdjpoXjtX5TVf6hy8rZ3vZcswK40qFmjiuyLCUcWFIKgSPi0W62Ngwgi4vAoRgFGcWC3SxG7vYTaUigkPdzCl2bSF5w0jeSBHJfTMHyVNdjFZPdTO9oHtOSTuFJXGW4JVkGiU1aJBVkX8V4JD@V3iRxbmFrjOROcwFmoegYoPPmqczaz@xkLaE1gQAMOIUANJC/MvOqJyZFHilXPwWyyghpZFR8qbZQGQFMRiL4E3xtO7ETMZrYFL4s2s8D9DYza6dZLIl3nvG/4ryL@uZj@ZfafpjMZ2zlP5Y9Cb@9x/y8RSUtQaopX2Uio8gkLGSedfTLoptnWNZVS9pgUNa3dl1XzkzlG36XrjURQtnnf5ZoevD2AZB1uVrfjB2zfoBpzfqxaA/8kf9R4/KsmgKme1m1S9rhvC810dsRivaAul6rX4Q9VZH1KnN/nkvjAJPwRHu50AvOwIdZyZj68n6sR9lMtruS5axAC18BVW30Qh74ajRcGB86ZbjGwVsiwn2XF3NYP1LT1Z5Ek8a6MHA6Z/9GjRH7u0wETpEFzsOm5@dg4FOhIuVqiIZ1iT9n1IvSINRUT9ZOXJYAqjSZyOHI/Jc9Lv9c9L6LqM8dmAzE@DrCWwg5A8GjIunfCxpy1YAGR4lTtPzXV30p@8uqn5ad3w3Lr@eBpAihqeGkzQGZYczqmvMrU6KmfqOvh/fIxvfo8X48ip8EmdZmlck8fuqfugkEChjgsbD29FA00lutabQSaESf4ZeJQXujGKLjdlawLRKWas6e75N/OHFbxG9xYi/n0f/xR1oitfu2n0@DXt1NCZ504VhtbhHiswhrEPZ6y5kz3R1MWvv3rEuyotI5ntQIUiNZcHVg0d1GpiIfRbFUYEM4Ft4HvZjU3zPRmUVSZyB0/DKU5/X53fRbqMVdPxx0HJ0Ts@Ca1p8SAs2lld3azgEHQu9vqz1HJq73DiVpnEQXTKV57CM71257ny2kixhzD28U84Y1ufTD@lTohlbfBXZraZ1wOrqMrZjr0JsfyLmmwTt6EgsVS1HZf6RnoS7ldsJQnSQ2bPkJdW6i8TnoRM36Q4zQpw3n24yfOobiPCFNt2H30ei21tKnWsVqphezqTDVc3u8XBRj1tcYXhSjpvuxpK3Md2dec5iNQGWiLCd75tCpiDDcqTZdGyI8mVhj/V7UzIB33ifrjdnVmnMEKhxSZZ0o5CX26xfuBmsjOv0iw2n9/QLgOfBqCEMZdqGPS0dnlxxStcfWFqL/kJKOkGxqCgk12hYuTLmmbJ/@RbX2ZxbZ3OqzmaqzngEpKu0MmWaqSp1L6B7FnVBJ2iP5khnJGHtTD@LxDb91@v7Q@xWfFkNV8uhp1avVsskkFeD1XLNIaG82lot7/JDtFo@4ofPq@Wf6CEZW6tfV8tmWCDDkF754QW@axGO9@Zqecdxv2VG/ucgMvXmV8txn1KeH@WVKUKkQLtJa8QRW6@vmzkaBjSxsVLpKXBM5GH5xPswHv8r0v8lAB2HpkIi9jgfcGa1pkqpScOaMaQemjZM6JMZI7msZ/PawR5bXsVZUM0arfHsMgye1PDl1bQwEsSQyica9EsIQm6WZ2OkrJnsjujo2olDuZPT9UvMUdYHWg6nn1Dm06QSjjqoy5v@SoOQDrwbnig8D88pdEx1jBHOZN0ZaIGov6wuaBT6Oo2L7n27h3ivO52JsM2ZLNJLDNaS6aTD8eEcR23tD9JMwqm4EhDaZXhTTgYluHeiGEsFPTLnJPNn3TIIBnvwu4uaY5UDaikRhMST4qmMsnheYFmMpETWWZqqDD5CwZI5NMKD5meO6LirHzmfiBuP54p505ApK1Wy5EqLSSqch/u4S38ktceL1xqcyn3f8tWUvMFeiwMAVsm4FpGv/e/Q3/uivxuF2hBhooJZivXsqXRavV44y05g3kmqne5AJHpq152pHMU1JCSn1YGlmS/itSkVHyYfouRLpTH0CW3fkC1eE9xCt8m1hcCCljC8Sn/8vE4fP6/PJ9S0RtK5yhulJY@aNBxpeIxp0rTFuErDZ3UxUnh/2@98dwcP0x1sdx7gcQOGEySXUT687LGVSzK2SWzLF4jUUlmJIOfj0ribk48k7vnoNj62pQ8HjcPdg/3XH2nSffLkiavn6HGCH0Yt9lrjeVwgsxl3PB/MWLasewi7hsNubMdHF/3h6N6nXnZKloiwJmXAp1oM@@kx7mpZZsnzibFL5SSvRVEN63MyDPyUVIKq42PKDjVdR0SQYOQ88DUQo94SvT1erbkcYKzR6Pld2PNj@mo0YLzUaOhZDF1jTsTdvy/fK1xGQw4oLdHxrjMZdq6idg/Uh1fVY3X8qqb23u38pD4evFMfqvvHcH7x9t326/qOon@1/aOayqRM8BBJFAtKoutu0Aw40vV6sfhIMeSd/mAscsfZceX7kd9Vr/rNAMdUzyO/@@JCXvK9YLQlpWq0HB1jDzPkyLHdcAR7Cw51SstYKDctvsaImweK8p7RmraLNW@33wrbIeXNYO07CIPI3HxTnZB6kOStuSvuiZKEqKZsOsTRimGBdU3FfcqPsxsC44v9FUiMHBIGtZVXmnDxf99NwePa4ZsjBY8rOwf7u/Xj@sH@kdo7OKTXtx/r@y@JnvWj48P69jskccY3B7v1vfpOlT8IAsW8giuUXy@j0UIU8sjOVGl@xsl3fkDdH7@ld72hwatrny90Rmr1sgfpE/qd8PegtbqZuYygvuASKR8VKGelevjyPc35KvgNJ5zmKJjtD7LvIo60u1JUz7k2GixbNN429XClaS9Xcvk8ojtWCLYVbLLfE4efPWWAsxFPKwxUdgc2Ktj7FvcoPJYNaKroHsEGKGOwUlEcJG911XvOILeotmanD6e8UpsYEeoXFH1hTE02M0wxbSsDoLhZUe9hP6i0GX8gvqcP67ra0VAyqIfxB8mgHskHqKJ12I6oxzrH5ejgEuJZbciHX7uDPT4WVk/iD9s@r2Kfapyk37hLfRUHGYWzmA6HQpRdHg7XLG6CUCTi/AgT2OnIwAgkQC3JRDlKZNs2ypklYdPGUYM2e5PA70glboCdkN8eRcqpuHl1DOOgoBdKEMrzjt8TE6jEdId5Tz2Fz6@Kvi8exsEb@a7KoM8MiMCxaTzicrtaKwzuWo5Kbk/V6GsbSQ6gbEzQbkNgewqBPwKGAOVSK50mz1R8xxZg@m3Nyk7UJ47Evu3f7PzEzq3LZpAqoK22nF/D3393NZG91DrJ2CkydtRFvwdDUiv5KLPdH9IYZ7HK4e4gBZsX/cEolD500i3gEyee5ig3Jjaq7ZfKVqo20GGyxl6/Z1V6Rlw8p9YzYsq71MocL2fnsfhK4qAT59MkLHZ3QMc/618F1tmZh0Ok6wDbL6QI81k5Nj/HI8ZE9M9MIjv@phA@@Wlla3f7U@5vv3iIoSxiQUKYG6ND/CPGRF00PPicjw0Wh9C79EgzsS@jyzOU1jZ4WlpilBtgtA68CGld96KxGaeJufH0d9zjmfzOH79@rUipHCSTjnsfXTiJdPPUianS4zKnSpuAWLKTkCVZ75gvHsOM5fUL3N1BL2wSRXqQI1i3T0SW1CLEtO7ssk2SRQf41t0dw3fVFltUGEVSHEnY/VH42dmurG25hcSgRFnkdIyI9gzkkutaZik8X02B210MjuT33cE9XYidTA/fBW13IbTvwi23Nh@WTEsWrLuD/dsCsDK5/SGw1HZvPmCZJKehxZweM6e3shxb0y6u8ZepvuOxR2Aw92IHJQZq1XbZ4yNq4@DekQKuDSZRiI6Od2uHhyor6xMqS3IPS4aWFoOAfU@9Taxtwx4Lu3ysNMWL5Vh5Ml9SFm3mv0WDeSbx5ogKrYN4mh6xsIjv4dCC7kaknp5ZWIVg63sWiIZyaey@GBkUnWjA32gNSMgmnWY1MDOzmcsy@YSRbQSu6eaJbmzb8LOFtczdCJs9HNuAbJsg/xw3S2b33wfRj8umHlGw4MAJDW6RJk3zDa0TjqjiAWXM59M9uKBbTJfCyF4U7GVDOxh@FdMa9p9nKGYkUcJFF7bEulaONWqiH68YNYcNEjEN@LD01Ili0UwJRsTzl@d2h7rJpOekpyBSMhFI@YXNFVT89Juewpga8TxZiRVye6ytMDYnBstT7M5q2JvzM92HLfTGpHiYrIqk7cKqcv@YqmSWSNVkaD6zMSaRIG88fvzwNtiTrTDFc38Wtswhk/Jz1B3Q@j4BGY0j3t4nzq3veyY9YYAFpBPTejNgJgqSqjNjTkm1nScjGz/CRfaFCBmEiEBs6slaXXUzgdts6DIj2dA5y1QbrCEcN1RGzRT1vy2uDgL51vrufX99MtiQCaaD32CV/6Y/jILkVp7lW8b6hEv46W/BcNjjbHKfqQsoDl9jWnjZjm/bicGrtAqJfN5mt6StbyeJ2a1n9hq4Et5ezCMcPXb3Nie393KlTbupe/XXNfWA3au2U3uR2WHWtWTPvbC3CAGWwbwvgemD7/Ddj8r0j3DwDEgiE9/mc5g27q24MUVIaz7hyF/aLFTL1tJk77ejpt@DNxIvez9SWe8HKsi7sLWDPXfWznpxM1WekIsGPYdKedlcPstF6Rs2dAEpDUJ6E9@tCQs3NYylJK7XnPdhH4WDreBGds/YctIvlJ4WN55luHU9b@R1T56deg@alayiydfvdaPL4XXr83n/4qqtOmrw69lNc/z7b0o9fgT/6mr9B/GfXdqoFNgD8RMF1@vPisy5GsEf2Rc4wqPnJW60UqsqWYdv3lMuP/CiuYwbEhNcqh50DRfiit2o0j3ZOK30KsXN7knvdBOX/EZrldFaac3Bhx9oFiUZIyfzJ6NTzKn2rmvQu1LwGstRifXVEMVXQ@jLG38Y9l9X91@mduOgAGALTNt684a6hKJfgjUb7p7ke8G1o7fJPAWOzUBByizxraASrrvzfjK2Y1ohYUa94pE2G93w37GbWSrmLwejPqcY15JgLfU1/JpZMteYiryjQFlOQuOAEvcLCE6Sx8HBkHwdixV1riTqWgl3J10LxAlKsjjMfspmcacQiOq7XCenmSgf@M0LINEhtforF8PdZLwRq0V53sWDKYc/5AsTxVM84gCEfgZ82oAqWHOP@NpHhpqP9xIe5AvvUY34ngwbyGdYU0QKzL/VF77fxOWfEwGE8Euic@X1FqfWvEiRlLuDvLkAR2zphT@OGXCtUjplCY0FbKmvkgBnS3GmEarVZKLvS9cgp9CK/tMtyJX4baoZcX5XsjNJ@Jxav0WgJXcpJ23hp5MUc6xiOVPMZLZIsXQrNbDTRcujNwENq7HaCTodQlposZSQA498v1fXvxbXH52gztMYeUnPTaXnUul5SRekklx5muCTTGU7U3b5S5Lvm8om2bypuiqKlZc89XQzTypJkndzUd4oP@o3wiTzVtyVwpVxwvNUQs5K@XlG70vKvVSZmMHj9BNJ1/y9rns@xjKV90W6fvxmdAcFbDyrbU0muDTfCzs/yqQVp4DNskRNpaQ4h0xVZlBV9B1MLU5Ig8M@Pw/brUoCZa1kJA6PmezW8xfZvFYyfnQm0ZBbjFMDa8YYsajEda4x4W74wiLVw8n3LBAME4ymzMjdMoXHuvDYAotc90y1cgtyaoBT0yaHeAX3Ir/ijxnsaeRMvuXZiUuC@Y00Xm43pwnEQvdedjaZ0tIE10Xko27UglkkqXs8CXG2kNi3doHjOgO5g93GNvi9WE7YgsJIiim6xyma0kmGkmHfeV2IxG@ZvxceZF76pGMPOsGNqmKZ4fMtrEzqgvsoiEYRHFCxa5zocjDo4NSRFb5rvkKtQ0KsP8ZxSwLRmtnzmToseyS/hyd9IZ0K5dUBIF/DQCRJiC7Pz3GZDDdg@9cQrdhxCUf5TLU3lg0NGjMP1@WaeaDgfIMFcCc8t5GQnpPRA0pHA78Z5DOko0Wk/WSkqe1QRxrm/XTcG4GfM5rSypnMv1yGzc87L3Ge@6RUfFiySHalj4OL@YePkgtWRCSTsA7PhY9LjzIZ62y4KWfDOQD01GtM9O@JN4OroNcLMlWaMThjREprFAyvglY@kzkM4kNgwAUr42QS97D7l8OmbO6Q0uUTM@KWcOTJcRhxGH4xP8txcZPPyrwMDq2S02bq6quwBQKaGyftPk6H@cACbgKEHijUDUZElAeuSqPEZ88aF9ZdutiIImrAz4l1NhGTodcfhU3qGd7JynQIlByDJJX1WhOYUH3Njo/LwflZCOB6TEIBg4A5SlqEQ0Yfmn8XDko3zJyx@6ZnCiT9@jxWaLgHw5Ckb0Jg7hUuZuFOHXz8qn6kjg72jj9UD2uKnt8eHryv79Z21fZHPuPGQTl7CVavDl6TdIlP0@XU/IA@ZKtHVDLLCZnq/kdV@@vbw9rRkTo4VPU3b1/XCRqBP6zuH9drR56q7@@8frfLp@8EQe0fHKvX9Tf1Y8p2fOBxraZYJimnDvbUm9rhzit6rW7XX9ePP3KNe/XjfVSGU/2qels9PK7vvHtdPVRv3x2@PTiqKTQss1s/2nldrb@p7eapfqpT1d7X9o/V0avq69cTDT34sF87VGwkYLVyu0ZYVrdpCYuauJ279cPazjEalDztEPEIwdeeOnpb26njofbXGjWnevjR00CPav/yjjJRotqtvqm@pMZlnFuoQv2y8@6wBrdJoMTRu@2j4/rxu@OaenlwsMu0Pqodvq/v1I42Veb1wRET7N1RzaM6jqtcNcEgalE6PW@/O6oz3er7xzRnvHsLeweXOvkDEYawrFLRXSYwzCDQWiLSweFHQAUduAM89eFVjb4fgqZMrSqoAIuKnWM7G1VIRDy2m6n2ay9f11/W9ndqSD4AmA/1o5pLHVY/QoY6DDI@EutQpe@41egnwkseiVkzhnM97k5V31PV3fd1YK5zEwcc1TW3MNl2Xmma5@Ej2NpECfvYM/C79sZKe/rTVQA3mNM7MrP3aGKPSTsHuzWakbWTq2yS8I5mnacTrpTsNJpp4kR6TbmsaQVnl@eNsNfu445pXEw2PrrRuYdgWS4CB33KLIhVp/dXuMDycqPxvtqghe5Ro@F6dymZQuO2EnobfFEuV7cRASWw8sbGT7ksdH@eItTWD/qgkw31cACBnEL9H8T0ze8GrioUWoEuhsv7AGy2jiI5NrnAUQqJRr7siIhHSZW8M8HvoWYHLugY8PlmA/uksIzkTP2I/vS@Ji8yOVgfSDrLdlehgEUsoxH@HphqpBJ2icB/tEeCsM1V5qMg@HzuFO3qsObPn/f7Lcd1TRnOO6J14Lnj3lL8LDifKJ6bLM/I8rGzDpsQmXU3qzDx@bMmmdL9kh9yyxz8aYz4xzXYiM8H7JpyVbxZrTctnR@kOCySPKVdW@B6BXcydL431b/WP2A1V1x/tDnx/VX8XcYW7AXhMpcmvBMud8o/r04lAw0w9sVBJAm1h4xCwSpj7E3izNeU8QKZrsMWLH9orr4IeF4nkpAie@l37DoxGw/DGxt7ksMvD6tvtt/t7ZHoBLaPnj5@srGZid1u/dWT34@oh33astexAc3jpKdxkjVKdkjx4ZFieRhP2J8ZuFBARniXN53GH@HnIbbbSFsyQZChuRHCf/VgopcNQIesYgcc9zKGX2eOTM0ATqqpLlrT9W9YxfdJV2Ie0MYsnTH32g3@AHY8/M0QjxukGUizGHv5Jc6l1QXLveyeMRXlxQ077kGWfNbwsbhxi2nAW11sP4vbtfymedvqxUhMGTFeudu5JCFxbxILZewqejKy37KfEb0BzN7D6MtfNb/R40ft4I7d3fnRqDo6IjLuxSWxT51sRutGn2jIp4j2AadqpqbnCrv8rkaKx57eTo4dg1ijgVFBpBvY@KYBb8Z@RCarZAvYF6uu@iKcCucdgLOpOVa/E@fOao6Gsmn8h@h345VCCazYyYlQ7TquI2OyfIz9WBhypsj0p@jB8P@JNJkB/zmtOAl6Qi3LCeCdKMlQhVa0fGWihNfmoME63UioaX/6mID5ZnfMRdwwfXpzI/driAS6d8bmw0d2e9h2ZhAATI6NDXv8xiZpFz4tnV5kXV0c5yS9ZnfgKD1XmKliCm5u49RjtcszZyt4cZUre01Wha@pqHohC7czHvW0ZJpYyqv7UVbAucb/R@EBb4DEA5659EKsVic5q6hHmZED2tWSNeG0Yo9JpJZ@m3tq90BZLjJTsl@ffBlCEegt4DPdTg570ldinpv2uMgzsTpmL3jwXI5lMiYf7bLujA0xOwHg3G/xZggio4yuMUF0BDq76kugKec@G4qgksTqMPEzCHHr5om0PK1ex9jzziQ4NMb@XU/c5geyq2Vy5MXBh8bQvi6fV2/8MaHcuVuzhcUKD476HmwXUZlsS@jyiALT7PeHpDr6aDfh6IVjN68@6E2HoBddDrX/QprPwqHekTBKP1UDtUlW7zzNiLd6Ri0KR7it0Mozf3CTugEsRMU9yU1uQznEvIZHt8ymY3izVlLO8yTlOdGE3ZIyEZ@rDfX1q@QSgmqXoQFTMIzixQXbbHI9OHeIh991f/gZcz9UoF4raMWeSS2QvBconVTvsY/H5kiaPuhHvKNBXYEdkJgSJdlIiw1VaY5@otlJ2zVlE@@Y8F3KLfn@emImNdZSVFHCuLp2Yr6NHHUmqLSuXYPGzkJL648ZlVkLrm9zF2PsLTR9bK2yn3qxSCmLElG5b1RHPIncjJ8@4klv8lfuRxg99AVn3FoFBcLQWXGuOi3nGD/YFHwIg2HL3hMlTablD7D9xkuffo950Wwdard/TX8UBWNaATQL4U2BYTScv/Qveo2dfsc/D/uhT@s0uJq/EYmHxzE/osPOh/3riAMcScRNK1NrnDyLfxlxw4b3@Fxy03LNFY2CgWObKYyG4@qFuIngnXMYASYxeZm/B5M@0uIyjx4nhTLp@6dsj1dyN@eWfViaVVhO9AFAC7itCQsKuUM64otJ1uXTzakMZ4syWDieqZzy3TkWeymMnxGJ@BgmhbFBZsoswW4EVmZzMT5p3Xgt9kE4hKOlYDdAKJ7I4c@ej7joJEV@hKVAWZWeFq2icopyAz@EeBjPJ/f6k38y9oTAn0C/9HAWt8xiBBZxbeNtKZL1ivYySriweWDIMpolMUmx8DzsWdcPOdDFzSTUdPJ4HjXY8oeUIu1mb4orMSIdWvggDp/TIJHTGLuYVFbVqst@O6CCVEdOcT7DBrfZz/LgxyGu7JxBMO1oyI6F9DxSNYlKCA89YV5royw@lW8fMevrd@21CQJWZpmcWRHQnazRXPgGSijzK461@kMSxtkJ6mlTj9Vo1B@s3pF6c2XHTM9ss2jddN1bDYGF2So0WT5oMWkrYzyONzOT@EwwTZpibGlGPITlKz/HbD5JxJtKA@Ot0hjfQod5NEvspuJJJe7vlox9TIpXsOg1E008pBh3OCndjL@fNKjhjfkSRMOU5VWDJUYDIqMxlkcL1ASZYirdnULMfRr3CXq0iHKot0W0s/tnLlEnjeSMy1OTlHJyCXrCcTsubZJcGrRhfAE3caLhxkIqVjhvvDEf5ZVyZ3AyjAQBCK04yCX7ULKDm3TWBB9xdIC204C1UAmSiJ62bAuH2Ol/TDD2yq83d7TFQ2OcK51uCqSbGBKtKjjXIkjmvjm9njRuGMoUKWiIzyBF3KIp2XRx91b92bZQPoIgpTlZW/oWPTTGVWuEDf2xkxo30IGTqnTJ1IhKD4QGiwYaC7RKOe8EslyF9hcOheNh3aCHES0g5LODnzVdAu68N4oxtVHkpjVGFleTW0abq3JbUiRhKHkH@fVQFFWXF64EIBCMqXylRBDg1pSxx6EAu96xOS@FqO4jKlgpYVjSR/aKmth5zkgHUXWGR4@tHMVZOZ7ZMHIzgZBiMTtPggjpLLOzJFBoopuJi5Xjyez2JDlIITa8LxSnrtC9kqZh3HNCQI6cXXQTiXJSUl5RczAnPnrsphJj/ubUZ0UrtTiZSvSJMTzJlSZTnxZTqalq19fTRVMliR6uXWsqkUjh2gjHUuHP/cdXU2yX57FNqLXISGkZ2j4bkc1plUnrtvyvkXrOl7KNjmHg2TfDzfKrISFWUk7ZFztgV6t8ZADf7X@6tcYy1WCiYwWwXzpz2cWRBSFrrFlM9WgWVrrG017soMCsaftt9f54by/l9vVsbAyNusHwcbFYBBOf2c7vjW01tpLCfiGdu9C@7HQKg@u/DN@fFVj2BwGHBCibFXRAXUKDIsr3h@cSGQI4UFbkzumLrFjrX7bbdggGnFCi86jbJKf2hqB4Agpjo5f3x7wBxCD1BPsLGoj2/aLi0Xfti6KpoZhjKCoNk@CrrDk9I/LgQxv22fFJFQODYDbWTDRvuZWtL5hBENmEO4vdF7tfEvPk7Kug0@l76gNCJMNTwNK3yQJ7e3aBomTBCSPf7r2M2B@tp4KrsGPdK0YWm9cBzkxMJs6E8QsP3/iHwXntZuBkT37O0rRCTV5DM9fgn9pT2fOsq53F3wGs8CGhfafcXX/gNJlOk5lpqtcjOHkijB6WvJlrn1QWl/fENM1uzw2izkY3z84aqOku6wLGlz13L7dkTvaYuNlPN6U2aFgUGBon@Fy5WwlcNfvnicWrUbt9N6nIYQCkY79LIkoklD8nEPkMgEegHn5ET3jR/ilHw3pvwqGIKDgI1jEtd1CggQKZzP1m5bdrp1qtqpXB2pqqVrfpIZdT1e2q2sWH7W21S@/beP@hsv748abI3F33C33cNh@/qW2CwTuca82L4S69UloF98ZgrY0uXilUVrzNlUbl@dZmVDipbuNaPz39@3/97//@3/5Hoapf/hdetvnl5Oc4Uz6fL6w0v6z88G0T7ye7p6srZycrg9PV801w2d/Za3i/Psr5iflofniWWZZZwPrKdqRmnc3eZ3RRZWL5df3hZ5IuZbXcjArL@mskkaNYxi43A@t7gHuUZ7SEN0EHJpfyGQR16/pjbMdT7zQDGODRfEOUJFxgByrl5WzFbNzDHUycIT5VWdaeeFhnvQpwpyXxpIC7uDRj5cJeFPSwA37FOq80L5Px6TccNTT/Fn5@E51v92/Ug0@OelBUDzz1IJvln9LGM/rqrhRC3M6VbLQcyGY9SkmOFmBmqKKQFT1eP3CsnQlyZzIrHLIHkIybCs4st@C8ePXHl2Uk4Fp0nllCuE8lWyR8yIQiy19Wet@oW75Qjm/Z1FUbVhQaehXDlVknKnH/QgXyIzEESGruCkHKfaoSJ318IxlPBfNF93WGowkxYJD18OUej3t8oLlopadtnlNrKYQ5YvN5@Yq5cVMuQzPaSJH6EwT4QEWWk0W@Sbi6vJoRK2@rldxMuYVtt08zn9g6jIORsU2XQn9TFhOINbdNuJWevteiDbnleEVlw/h4xaoqO2n7rTJWke5lZxQO9HUFrh0D6ktc2zcZSehRBiRwxGd/eXqE8UaB8RQ10S0SLGusWn00XUZCT19Npw5283JyZBGh8LNDY/vrxNh2C3xLxLCD8AAjFZvytf2wE2mvK0Mm9rk/PEN0QL/NAdVGcm7G@3mI2jqBcb8dI51nyGxynoxnasryYOifd31PLe/3j4f@uE7TFmk@o2bepRbCBROQwODTVc9qnkFYWqS7hCkSN4UthxC8oDPW4dGkb7PxnRN0qRkK2u0KBkGKnZiSwddUX03QMeHq7@gEG@Up4R2fRmoRy5IXlkYaUta@NsPDbGroZEwN9tiJB042I6jGI9Pwgi50iYm2ywe/JMk78BGg687qW4D6KsLGM9SP2ek86PmpyWnQyZiL/oVNJfMixjOHohRrpIyG8qSURLwDVqRH/pz2AiFzk3FnlFlynKVPkQ7ntmzPI@zkO7bFL/gqjAPQcQAzvhmi3vVCEZYTM1QSAyOv6mz5TxDaHf@c8Btf@2Ow4qdl58d7Bffk50@90wfOp97XT7@7jIkWyWaWzallfZhtJJYeKzQzFrzUq7FKi4yrwU@9dIZPPSV3WCwSECIF5@TnwunXAiH0adl1HxQ@LQtBUl0GTAqL6ysAfGEKzeU0FoXlzJL7wDWd7/xYchXNrfyLPpQPrvwSFmZRydv0tM4ZtgkU39P97VKunESFp@vFR@ulR7QSOg9ucsPgEvNtLro8C25IlYiwnKWp59PvKW5IEeLbTeRv0scbaqeENZG7J5G@pKRFqB7mXE8mZisqkxeeoPxEZXaXiisubpzHx@EjFvyeIpYzedkXlJgOWtznYP6M@l3U40eQa5O3Q4QjYWUgNiK8hZoDZBN8ZR6Huma4rPI9p7zage9WBkLdW1i2Zotev5fTypqbX92EEo1bM52nxafFyTE6NURTI3RFK1Or91Rp68cn//Y/D35bHi1vrRc@DOl3tPzb8sbTZXmkB3p7aN6ulreWnyPbxrflcYHWwPT45N/@N5Xf@gvBQcr4Of3ZemxgbYyXt3IVLvJ1eWuDHkrr61Tv//nXf6U2rMiKDbFYVxqeYsQ2DUV2/B7zLqWrOlopy9LVRKzwxSzAEAtDWpvTCwyjbtafFnmbbllbVVwF2vOVsUfRUzwbZo3YVEh2Mow9BWlGUqCCCnIC0phQtJVlu2HMNsC8CZrql/v5jYhWAL9oc464yth0434Ek6EVWRZRBzpSI63n5WGr@GM2Nu8oZ41NyaZRIbG007L26cNNYoe3/WAUNtNWEma4dpv@dXCWBx/mg9Ylral6Uaf/67BwRSzZLa0/LbSxuV9gO@7CgCHlBuP876QI6mBAtDBko1NPDakH@l248PI4WhAp9HvxmZSJJ0la9iBoyh5WOiYxZZE7fp4cD6M5@USVdvgvKfCInKkDQVqx0j71qOTBYVll1@KMko/XvC6wecvGsdoFRk6sYQcsm/IZbgN2B0178tXhOV9C4lLwui5Z8n6r1fB1mpNZyppQaV5m6SLoDCrZtrh3h@9UnJho@ouaORdKLsQOQi7Hgg6wusHIpyV6JctfsB5PaoCbFH3WGruKS8ja1nn1qr5V4agrC6q@lqqvqUehJST1xDxjeWNTdjaRLRVsVQ6DBo7UZlZMtUUmaPMwzz/AIJJuqbdxLUE3h29AEtWS5mirMrvbPF4LE49cB3JnT7YWJXJ1Zjm5/OiZHHKDGroT6s1LZSQg4AW3DAtlej@SGxAVE2Y07GXEn99EsvHvocFwGw7gStR2WyfOR2Va6l0h9k044ruUikig/craNtgZmT1i0LGLrTgEbRYbL1kXLNUu82KLM5ruKHMYaOMSKpuVfaqTporDy7Z19FoJFEEfssXS@sNHjzeePH2GKGdLurWzwaBQHquAwYVPMFijdmiRje@VSnY1K58Qgnq6SkCfBRYHcDDrunZd4/b52r1XKRU1sGKWYV1zGA0prrcrGWQCcRjkMSPQGsUZZh3nx/IJGnb6qeV@pX/E38Y/IDOccUfrC@mtfnibeKbKdMXhQIUFMzvFcR7Cg4qrU@y8Qb99CG8TAWxdhe2potfwADG6GPYvzy9s7shr11bHNGCI4OyXGiuol8EocTBmYQVdVG841K3bFxUD72S6BTDKxZQAnU@A0zDTfit9bWmK0bFKkxA8a@LGKo4QLdNRm52ZO3t9VdvfnURs2Q5Dx3DztmUrKXfsyQwOZBCr12ruMVFXe7vgq6RaJnkpr8os4IrIV@Lr8D7uSjcRiNqiipHVrDeMnEVkKTEvJq5Nk6LUj8BrBsxS8XZSmnutphUgiBGEejcpFmJefJ5jkyzBye5kjFPwcrZs2Yi@CaOIHczpyrKutijlTBxVYCkzByD2bYpZaUixjB7lxxoHXpbeRjBHuRWNrQFthhyvVIOZOTnMBFvdRuIAG1HHDS3Q/vr@jqd2a/Rn78OuB0V5u/oT2h2HeJ6Pb0njWyqr@p7pAttbLNvcwmbqN1xRImYpaoexCYIQvm2JihgkXgNq9T1NexnUJ6mxfZpwBdjV10q42R3VgwSOXngPZEkv3mNXHHxdh7@VZfNqWtLELlX0sJAtrsUD26LJUlJrDElIeQcQ65MgYkctCbcvJQwvFuiseft67WIYu743m6dTLCsLKlLb9wpE9jTPzqXMIrZY12yxXkY/LuIL5tuFvHEWtPv6LlrMHLfwxr0/xhu5uzNH7v8L5qj9c7jjoeaOh2XIHuGO2G043@jkMOz9GRxzNuY5uNEKz0PsD7WtVzSi6FkAWOABQ9whpcRSEW2bI06UMzthbXI@gpHQ@mNcDPhDjX@kG/@oDJnLj7vB/6uNz/2DG/9YN/5xGXPNjJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JEJXTSH2Z2L9Rdyeb@0ZZu6JZulDGbzujm//SW5v6DWvpEt/RJGR4T5MBB3Ncv5mbRRKpHO/V6Ym6Rz2inXQ7i2M/mShdrr1YlS4uHducyuqhAW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OIuIbUPjtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStZj@gJSoQ0b2wN9UKFFHJPEpPTpnyiPybSN5587oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEJTcZ4qL56iCZ6xvxvLLLPpDVzvHh67X/ImTo@p/1LTRCHl17HXQ6Ziaxl2DHsdcp3RirOYB9pNccKVbR5GRkR/q2d8wuS/OlGju2mJgXZy8S5KgN53@0lupC37CicmPLiGiT1@XNqgqmuWZ5IV@o7ZJpdpN1i/8Qlz7TXPqsrA71wmAeqXy94ad5MVmnrT9@vGgOkFJ5/GAAFj3Kv2BU/V8)

CSS script has `#` comments, `#` must be the first character on the line. Unknown commands are ignored.
CSS script requires a space on every non-empty line that doesn't start with `#`.
This presents a problem for Twue and Ruby, which don't allow spaces on the line with `::=` and `__END__` respectively.

CSS script has functions, which are defined with `+ funcname args`. `+` must be the first character on the line.
Function body ends when empty line is encountered (a line that contains only \n).
Functions are not parsed until they are executed, so lines in function body don't have to have a space.
I hide polyglot code in 3 functions, all of them called `f`.

I couldn't hide the Ruby's first `__END__` on line 29 because there is nowhere to insert `+ f`, so I switched to using a [percent string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).
[Heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29) breaks fish shell (`Expected a string, but instead found a redirection`), `=begin` breaks Befunge-97 (because there is no `b` instruction,
see [Funge-97 Spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20031228193410/http://www.mines.edu/students/b/bolmstea/mtfi/f97.html) Appendix A). Can't use `;` there because of fish shell (`Unsupported use of '='`).
Also, first character cannot be `+` because of 2L, so I ended up doing `''+ %&`.

I use `%&..&` string, so now the code between lines 29 and 179 cannot have a `&` character. TODO: use `%[..]` string instead, which handles nesting as needed
(`%[[]]` is a valid string). Note: Ruby doesn't allow using non-ASCII characters as a string delimiter.

CSS script code:

```
text 0 0 405
```

Answer (score 1):

## 411. [Shnap](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/Shnap), 17265 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
pppppppppppp ; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"F :n^*giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1*_e#8g= ma :s561?<p>3equr=0+:
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({f4080679-97b7-4ffc-b464-bb2400489f5b}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKr4xJtvipRUKumWbtdDLaluXV@SxQJJkEQJBFgAKZElsaK7Z7fXbXtmPT1tR7vt8W33rGfb64kY78TMuL1jz0TY@3HCMZ/8A8qPjQ3Hhvsf9J6TCYCgREp12/aGY0ECyOfJzJOZJ8/Jx0Fb9wY//WkML3LkWLO@5YzJ2PDGpOua54YrkgczsqObXk7VOA5D7br9ydCwx16ZixGFEEu3@xO9b5CeaY0NN0M8wyBtw3IuwF8lZGtiTzyjWwObRohtXJBDu2N2AQIZO2eGbb41XPDLEvLQsK6GV2PScYZD3e56ZOSa9pj65gg50sHSm3TOiN72xq7eGZuODV55Qp7blj5sd3VCg49cg0UqEADVOaNxln2KhDxxXM@AFJyO4XkOOpbAUXdN5/Hu04@vhVdk8rEOmRpZxvRa8opCXpiG270eQyWfnh4cXHfVyFcFxyYHN7OkZMnuZOwcjq/Dz5HdvmHrRBVLonrdMw/IHBtWUS7K170KUJ/G2OwspQMeB6YLtav7tUg6ug21hXWZIsZwNJ4RgdW/bllh3XpE98jEm@gWDWdPhm3DDQJ6Y90dm3afXJjjARkPTC@MR0N7I71jCF3DMofm2OgSy4RITs@HAqDtLjkzZheOC1Xuw3RsawYRjY7ZMzFKkA8AiFdiPDAYnKE@g0q2x9A4iE48yIZlBNCSXAzCPzTakz5xJuPRZEwgb13T09sWAG3PSNfo6RNrnCFt8AMkU/eLgWH7jRnAiQDi1GG5ej2hWTMWbV7vdokM7RjycWYQE7BGs1UmmgbuxHEBaxAqyJEPjLZrVkZjCnUGVdRzyiQny@C/H7pgbnXLc/zMLGcNPW3oq7TOEO6R6/RdfQjY6BoUp58eHhGv47hggxvDsv50G5iOPiZbWyS@//RhnNTCahHdNhdWUZVcQhXEAk9yrlsTaCHRmnCgftwwNodVFt@Il0kc0KLKJJslWei2RaLmAEmKXAID9H9VU@DOE7VIsgr0oBzR1EI8g2n1XL1vWgaD1EdIBWz8EESFp5wlmlIkWl5jofuO1WNBOzTRAtGKJF8ghRwpwLNESiqkiklkiVLKwZ2HGyCWIEsASNUgg7LKgC36ALRZbHd7pKcPTWvmp0CT6JCcQgoAFfKuAHS1CFDgrWl4a3AXEdryFYU9HgDmB/o5gBcs8wwpkxESJ6xOCV5SKiVR6ojklyXvDTB5QCMgMFckBUg@DxjJQhYAy2oRks/JrCDewLAsP9rAw2g0twUZbsh5AXBRhJqQAacyIrUAN9iB9qlA5FSgaCoQKRUIi6qCWcMkIFwe/PJQrfksS2age2eQEEtH7dIKAOoOYBTEOBI0BZEEEKDWCKAaqjwLjULDRpHTCOQf8lLIE6BpRYUUs6RYIIDPkkygfhTIF7YYBWipAvlREBi0AwUaggJ5UgDbCgBVtBzhIshWNPSHuBrEBdQoWYiTBTNUnJLHG@JB61AgSQXSVNXSokFC3tQclDen0Zaq5qF2C@AHeFMhryo0KRVyqxbBH@MWAYdFbMjQfBkidMQD1Ao2fWiLgIwc5IfChbBgVgt@49Wt0UBvI@VmMds9jJrHLpFHNEJUGYsH7yxiE7IiAxjsDZB9FVqARnsOvLNh8pYCQOoI3uialFhbJtAxJcRQIUMb5Gt9NF6gTcnTHI1m40HopjI3B4ioCYTQ6OudWegJvTATei5c8xq6qpTuLgDJWXT1gMo6E89aAAkNWZUmZZyb1sKtSN26ht7tmd7g3SKvWZpI29DHtnm2SCWXy0SQqkc88uix5FTQomHHpgBDV3@ApkVZ1AKGGTlhBS1lWVFo9tpGb2L3DaFUjOSP@own7hgGmUWaJebsmv0@jM8LOEqGFpMOmgvnHM2hpWljLnRE7GKarglD@X3SGQBzEXqWGPxSaQFDUxHGTG/jCC8ARwYjQgnHsJ45Je37HTqCLDKoUTx1BuYoCFxeGzhSuTSRaTEfaRsUc2@Lckie8WqKrx3TTsRJPMnNORh3GJcZHbVhcHuBIxaOwdh0YYx1KAexIJ8JOxglk4C05QEfRmALyChUSkfH0RjHJoOOrQEccywSSARYQsM5RxaWDpBLyXh0EG27yLECx9M1XJdgWGBzvQwdbr1J2zPeTJCnWuSrB@O3AcN8TzetMAN0HNHHlBmAd9yD9GbL2e65zpAONkMcTi3HGa1hXWDwvkBAj5wLY5H1xdiuj0YWcFDgbjAGDjJzoVPemzLq0VRZhiASxoMKB4A0KeA8TNfoUNz7RYfYGvAoy1ksE7V2X0MoDyKslQadBdgOD@PYE8sqA89jdIhWk7rGuYQujP1aZrswDwFDBmyVD6KtA9@MOae5CCHdV0XK6p0GNes5w@WisfH1MCz6wEQmybrQZ1B7PRhajak@BO6eIAsNPZcMocWwGsSaAPkFi3VIuo4dH4dQLlxgaKHQYUko04w4GZtDAyQhB6JgjWdppnF0pzlrz6ApU2xlRSr6sJxcQ5TIXUcUc8hGHFhnAdavO@kg1jBt06YtCNglD/l9F0glc@PGLmk0dLhd4O1GvrQnogEDnmDWIsKCx3q7z4V3KETkVw3bAxHDE4mJshi0/L7Tg8Z2YULZgWBB1AXsDkUCoiB0moodkaMoxwY0PLOISTqjEQF3GJSgeR7IRWBHndcmeQue1gDEic7EdWdkOoKaMIcQatxxej1ovW@N0QBAkGGXdGYd6J5QybT1eANbH3Fdh5KZzmi5sAvbpgFhbBRT9o5@nvQNQD6wsD2UV7HhL4oxGtGCUIToNmNvbR3whQXpjGYUOVxsEaPnOCK6dx3Do03Gcc9CAoCJeUafdhDobb0FSRoiuw5t1aZiRhfoj9/JED4myK0sDCblt4WPDRs6UAfaJnR9qESs2V3SA7E7wsii5KF3OsZo7LcWhxI1045IAM8OUAKgroIPTPQG3OYO2brWdiBo2H4iHC1KRJj1kS@Y6EhxfdleoOxHKIQy@mLNbiQPIc6vpc6/wjBLOXjFr8nDiHYMFIcoqZiMkaAgjTQ7A6SIY6Q5lOuGPudObhYf3KLJu0Mi9MK0MTcKEB9OlEInzMd6GALc1k1A4shCWLUlBwy65HAHaN0broDshJm0ulFXUdJFII13AR06trMCKiAzhItBln1oXdDGeIK0Q7fCxki7i7dUR0i2F9NNOJzBSDoaOS70DEZ6ZnRugVZZpHX5InkiHDGSInmwPMDCwBHHYX@MYyFEGFk6tAXsYthTQb7SgV4AKWMiM1A@h6UYyTDt9RSWn78LOgCwxgQjqm0bKKLp7owBgeLBIA0JzYjpukAMz3GoYCNRMKSItJ3CyKB3u0hfER20319PXMQWvTdpm9PrcnkHHcXXHneuu6SHIrkLrAd0okS858WTFepOY0a8eMkZjSUalT15CEgDiVDliR5I@TBUHAChOZnZnQS/1MX4DOEn416RT4IBIzJOjXwCAsP13KEQgY1meAb9mtoqpA@DuCDAU0A3mhP0kET00F3gNqATgqxZKnXbOrkC6uESYbrHBJJAMFHEbJiWYXfDtHxEYF6i5RVZEp7boQYhMrZhCTA4LTkdJJYQ@IGYoBF5cJAkf4RFB8rzMT/K3TDHiU1n5kiCMSRJchmywDAAJGhmTGBBzI45bvlMy/37AfuyUa1CYwOeCshmNxmVa4MpTBEoNQQWKU/iJyKOnZMx9o1EEsqLgecsN8A8QUut1sjleOBCj6P2OQeBAK2cjS05QKxfz0/Ns0n3ekXb6IiBeOx1wDqZnTFf4YAFYL2hehtW40tYBdk3jljFxovxKegbjZe6YoXyfjDX8JAJrvpZidRwAnPgt9WVKGJRfbdFg96bdSyfJWAm6OyMGrUh@2f@1FZIiDI@TxB02hs9lQHB7sDgkKPd00dVvy8yT6lt2uUlB8vp6BZ13sTgfBD38eGD493jn2@tgGGZ7fJ1B8nMFvM41E6mQt@eSFlRLW9GYSwAP2zdDhsjLofhOd@bCM40wirNOjC4TAN0Pjv@6nWUACeE6KApgBnvaywNCwNMF9fWvcG1QZj002lIMowShCXCIQlghgbMOvrrQX6OJm/fYuVdz9TId8ecWROdAQgcpUM7iCei5zUGLPBq99iISOMCL2rauPSwMEVDBvn5GHnn65mhDHWkyXz87GD/uErB@rNrAg0ieWPgpXS3K0KbtyYgiK8KA@QPTB2SFhcZR66a5nUlgjudJQQv6pasgQ8AUOIRHSJYw6Bo3gDyvne9bNRV6IQtgNophOt8ZZQf6nzZjEbygUNcBwXfVaMo9VgMVqHTyhEr9F0etjq5nFHIlqLDVmeRZjcKlC4TwDgQ8I0ueJ15ArqICy7SZ6v97J88vpFxjzKRIAoIQc48i4g0Lc/iUHoRTBL3pD2Q0xzLEF9QiscTPilJ8WClQOx4VASNhN@fmuOEnGRvJQlhIfXd3UP1YRDYn7im8xlUaECJHEcmt4crfh0P2ojtWE7fISmIw7jDIEFgm9YWc7fv2DdqSEdHLGoMFw2B/uL0jT6CscZ8S8VHGisqtLLlR932LoBKK3kNkUQxREFJNLz4Wj/XAV2Lcp8cfr4Pg4iSk@XQLNMLUBCJQ9GFpk7ElToQARIS/fysLGC4gHijtwceQmQFDwvtE7ow4u7Ce6UjpZiitDL8yix94tzA@Gtndq1pgQtrWmCIoOzw6dHjw6f7T3Y/a4zVXG7JnpVLeUAcpNcGXkgcMLxhb02xronFQnAx6Bsudi@gAhMQUIL1o4nnAuEWMYjIMrCm1bCl18QnzsCOe8nrhblAX@G13WFN6Al2PhbUjwiCdtdCYcRl69c4nmP7GYzHI68sSdDLB5O2CEKr9LrjWHpfovFgYLAsSUHR5fAZzm54q2JAZryZwWKwKS5gHWZ0HlG3hg4IL3QVHEkDSTDwdO7KMvsDkIVxqdxwk2LYgmlppC5ICCArS2HZKAGmNsCt/w7qiWdN@yNFLbJ2rchqVuKDYEvdH8Ju9AwQnRIwWgEqktespHG/cZ/MgEojpOtAYkRM0UkOj@BYYBFgJOncKcr5AXIotcBZU6QVFEdvJjinC1RKysnZgpLPSSCWgZgGPKuAM2/CUB93BsLYEQCe4PTovEGkFfa8jm73xJRvCDILfN89KKpWf9lo2E1g0Bv3ad5wJbo@a9aVZrJCbkZJ@eGTFWi9S8XDths4QNulRmia9E3W0LOufpOcdXXau7pEGg9H/pgjjMiTXWCk3jpAr7tGtO9hBCnqKaWWwkoY@J20YkLIwqgcPhBTEnQoGGmh6UmYLwGYXmQPoeUA3YpEIIvZjJBhmo0HQD80ktijpuRNDhedNZ9qLGcFp4bF0QxIHg2ERFvQMEOBB01wxCBgVuIgAiHHg/5xlgW26SRCylDux65nOnGPLtYga4XTtt4I6pHOendwoPBwonIMA3TY@XCggPaF4wS5MOI4oa97bNoUIvkbD4L4IC6GEOjyQDg1bodbLaAd0lh0hgCIFzRtnL8dLKY7cd4BGjskSPOE8x/AxNh0GaMPhYTIrCC7rCAsJeqyXKQz27mwEVrbIEWhbY7ZqoMzcXEB3uxGywbBNZWFAWi0cJGhha7Ut40Om@5lkWkpQA7VydAYOjibAQwepUYGLYLOVvlRHPVw6hx6tizg0iXAF8jOHhDSjsGmrIQhynHQqvdJfOxKu8Lnki68hQ51C3uHhY9UsV/ppwEClvdc0IkafxKWMkjOkAZ6Qad80PNBwHH7TQtbFq9XnZFhXxc7mVCaSFbo3oh4nK1GXcY3Njbi5XgtngHTNpi20LSNpjSYtqlJoCYMJ6KJxshQE/rWaQx0a8bn9QDyNNnENjBF5uWtOUro9XJZa2b0uuK/VXwnoSoA8xBawBfAiSerVTQmk3ztAhePQISIlH0P285JxzVHPgo@AZ6E2aPdi/e7l2tUUDy@HSPDqgtyq4FcbsKNN@pyo9m4bHTTjXk8g7GTFb0KIirQz3FiKPZdZzIC3rGeLQtAXpN1rdystKtxOZ5KJIqCBQnpyeS9YjKtM1wn4ga0qUSjEQeU@tipdwYuhTfNqMlkiCjIR88EQceyEnHxsgjpt5PNZDoOcZPxDIwM1Xgc8EJXPj1aaJyUYI3owJwCKqFjwigbXdygNJqukmF3/dwYDWZuNEA48QeMPk7iLzbQ4D4jHEiihPotix/lKZcmGwLWm4UD/hrnD5FlG83YAMOxnDakpe1awdB/LvSGzliXPhVBbhMjI3Z8Iy4JAgzG1IdBosV@YnrYhXXbcCZedLJz5Rwspg6up4MJEMtgz1wGWpU54ozOwCHxzR2ATsKFJyT8uIYmsJW4AEC3I8KNRBQZI1y1AQaH7nIygS7S/WF0YkihmWCkJ1geyOVHb8QwtQqNQ2RMyOzbjmsIgBKIwdEtXXSjIFcLFsgP6eTbjeHH96WjKg5lpgEU8cBydIpbRq4jC1OjYSS@3ccox0aXs4B@9IA8iqwuXKMrpTi6XOy4AxghoDRIidWwtoa@h@R4o644nkJULoFjftSTCZjA916Qrqqq@U6uVw78sFUAsgdQSSgY2yBlB16CAp5Jv5L32cxUME3w9NnDfTZ9Q8d7HOFxKq81dLoTYG190e3YsPsZsg/tybSdoQloCOK/PbOOHWfMJhrAsm5yiMnt5nBi6XTa6frM0K3xOk7bsehs1G1RF@EnrqdbOpsHC3x3P30C4sbz05OqWI4EkvTz4a1p41To6mQZPg@ji5904TdYofJYw@Q3czyOW8FWVCQzvkcePSb@RlSoo8C9gO5Bl8JlHN@9iO5D3IQK7Lo/kUGtoaMfsEQD4sZU3IXnO14q8hzd14qBYTiFhmO86yK3l4pK3c/Hvd6Ss0adzwQkTdbCOUud2QbVJTE1mqUcC4S7VZfCRAHlaZhw0@racAUajm2zEcPFzSfhboiBYQWrm8fAseAKHgz6FvJVIDehlMA2lhrA5I9woYaSblz@Ix3gg70bXCx0tpHAQnOxDdqBYHCTkKXhNiXiT79XaBeyHX/Z1GNk1XEzbGZnq8aW21Gsc5lEKbGFgc0WgNiqVYKdf@uCYUrxeBiMQqV5gxi0mHSHwY2ihvtFPDrfz9EoFc6TQKKZqrLQmBb2m1dxyaNo6BG@0Zjek9XPQDTCLZyb96W@UaGbrdbgqxL4xH0etj0jAnB8GIrNnXcGQGdIerqMSqifid1zrK7AFuqgwRAm4mEF@bslwq2l/g5iw3SDXaV0Wy@LivQ1siH1BtxrVVq7GSCyhTUEBN3nklydZc6vSB2GvHPRG1nmuEnm4thpDfwtW/b1za6MB3VdfeZx/mabKtk9/vjTutxkELihjotvRVaL02DPNDDOwCjh5nYw4ZahsTmmnADdEmFieRURMjWl6zSQfYDBEqiQMCG/RJj1K@NqUZaeAcJywsCce7NhhhjJudiz9PHYsFmbYyug69HNlqr8ZKo0@W1/3aNMZLo4BJypiX6QxQo5OX24f3wsQsv1EvF9XEQqQ3fUOwNgUNYVOsBktPBlcq8bJ/cwThJnDjjoaiB9tPz40Kgr0OhB/oDUkXb0DTcBjklc/@mAM11yoxEZh@YjCDd@dcYURyGwhJGEMlFg5ZX5f24zUcvPZxlafJpiEtCduF8G3JpJcWKbb0QPBhrKt0IQX1iF8aK6maBUbFNJ@jv7hrh6DRIWZRqhBPU6Ed4ClYPAPGk2K2wbAoRFAcztI3Z5nlYF3VpfVYKqr4IzsDQUgh@9@o68rMtCqZneXAWK7nLzd8Wz8kfgIoRl0J6xMtnNBO3vNzoyywNbjmSU@zkVp68dCSmTTWbg2bQ3DR7s3KJEh270Wt6wtbwdDDoZkhI6G4QFCUhCzD@z4LdZ6k8pP8g8GI06JJLkMkS6iignV1cUh2RTJRSHYFIIq4x5IH0CYXrsQGke@@cVotwB7a3@Xhbssw2OD8Ss5cVi9GEsvHR@jTsVzvloPMYdmvaZQ5ecQlNLFpUccoRh7OGZdTMm7oalj6WgYR5YWHVd7rxhu0cfKwLQlRd/TZ860Dl9nxcGJlKXjumLTu@vSHl5H8tSsv4@WTrSgpkIb@4IKZSKNHCv3TbXBQUk4Aa14L0iGBApbM@qmBWV4AAETsXAeASEi0kvi6Jf3wJFlvDub@j13//t613A/83aGcBAgZOfoaEFQzfWlNBbW1l@VLTQx@qKZXP0E8vUKWKo6S6QHd2FIulWaFgNmu4DEAQY/oe4quHXOLRNfADXeEszYzlni5LBe3Uiq9b1bCCZnXVhr20JY0nRFSgQ7LoUCYwJMg0aiZIuVgnGlK0CRURsJGN3ZyrYt0VoY2b1PpiMJ@wJjOudlWiO8L6tb/oh5ZzeVgyJbaG/pcpd/WzSdYTRWT/kU/Mrwi5KT5ehBWAH/BXpFhpXF58VkG1JD97rgi2GNumCvu5qFZ498UZCm0rhXWajHWF4SwquxZ7rgpj@icLQsB5rpkUfH9gSfejQUPwNGRJuehUiSDOvodnS2zPkQQZfvpWFmxuA4lQ76bSsrVndHo3Wx0dJksYvlVbHnoodho9VcwQS21grsFk0WmB/q@0dtQrDlTnULUHtRoxrifmqvRE3gobLqjQOngKhR0FubeQ4IHUmlu4uTLc08UU@gmWEdTPS/rBxZHYcYAdGRCmIihoMHZEBg5LMYHfeIiHc10wfkR0Y5io0BudahNC0mgQ4nTHuWl3Tpj6AoLHdorgnN9JIRGcdpjrOBd5r2YcBiKbsuXpEe7syVx9AnASrY@kwjq8dDpYmB3Hy8Y6GemF6Bn2sRuzZyoyOO9ZK9@UuEEz7Rafx7mrWnmk5Hjmhz9sQ1HcBC@y5ukFHcWnqtkAnw6PmW2hQsM1iUaG61XesfLEv6fBYW@sTt4d0339/KIULKZSi3EGhAvbHsRX/vZaun0nu2V0VRE9OurjFNmK8ZYhdRab8tZf1pQPBABfuVpfsQC7SmKLEpvrWJIxLLhf6LHj/DEPHOtQGQ8doRtlp4O4wQqkIhrHLWOyfJbXs7al1P4wo3QBbuKsQkco9swwYrOjzRpUSVVa@ZAxFlj@cRPWsiTExVgoaz9qvDTzrf4uQ8eGZkv1ibPoz9bg4gGdkwlBvfcnwg3KN4zTabiUmumV2jLtZmWWiNgLue4Si8xEYjtBwM0bfnoyWanVJOrOPb0fZYBR0aae7lDv0@bJ0qHgHp7TEn3sGvW@VmJiEh3vUqjlZln0GJrLismS5TZLSwrivTfZcSpi6LFJehMVVNjdiXJ0GRUt0F@RaEqSuE@xp4FJJsk3bGM/w@YHUtO041pepKSCqeHLZAWlVoLt9b6uxG@yOf46FLKYuPJzwaPfWTVqw0caXLQE/KDTfVunRJaEPqk0BFz2HuCC1bL19@iaywHRXKnjKFueE2P5faz0v6c@GKGJRLNza6xiH6rQNS2evaT57G7ySqN0Kb5lo@Iu1uLjLlnQXS/Gxa0RpNANkmV2QUgbG0KDWW7h8vYt6O/zX2kBTB@913lPD6EjTfaOzLsDIBLpg43NpDTnCLI0dG@SrMW41RDnFws2svus6Chys@q1E8uFQ7xtMkcxtlHIxYYG7aZhYtzCunroosx00HYi20BCyvklApzozZl7wXgnwyawD9ToZ3j3ddq3zd3AO9AN6@7pdtDeHWHvgDOyBMWBb10Pbus4B7XHMFP/clnXIdX@Au@lGo6Vd9lF8Wo5lfQg@kTQyQuk4vZV52sdTuHh47EvBZUf@/dedk3f6mNEONKztNQNjAuOS54ydkSFQ27qgFk70sOc6GhosUv@sM0i3yvmAkeD9s8K/U7bs6854NKKv1siaePRBowr08PRdfFOPbU2h@zIdty@@dYZt0XcU/X0rdAl8NYlpm@POAE@vs5Zt9J12Z2DelWlfY4YUTPkw6wfJrogZkwgP0Vm0TECvOxOxvVSj/if4OlxX6f7sERvWQsMt/MqqGTp6PlwY6Wcdj82GoomUcUI40hvZKfIyPYdffjMxxwugkb1M4fQuW5ZAw7q8@7sn1nJW9JjGggz7uyrWtlLKpCNDLhgyMDzKumSX97lFupimsce6DEVLSXMU2ZfyZdDt7/2hs4NmZN4W3Jfa19KmpZWDnD2Y9L2bBJNN13eBRcPH@mkLup06MmUNY5Zu@691aFYtCc9ZwrsFPNfEuHVNJXfrogoNp1iC7pjwasELqm6ydg7NMkceexKht3Ypzt/LBLL49fVChpvZamHar5iu0WNLIGi6i0UcOi7uRAYeROjgSjrOoCMxZ4wXI1y20weiLlhkETgIu45tWblNaHX1h2Om8NlTo6/jXuvH5hg3a65oFbTJrtpedCfsr010z/zaBEq2rrGh6gi2DOlGtQugbQW8J3rf7Dxaqogwkz6C/Z2e7LXU/NHpZl1cDEwPdzSFhlsmprDJsUaMra4FcsOKkNfn7UOtGYsOxE5irgy9am7dGc3wwNqMmm6bVjfHdJbVf68THddtArs1ExeT4Wji@a/VeaB7pqKz0MMz6u5dmABceAOklQx0a7x6pjoy5QpcmD8oLozruPHPTcvpk8@LMgGmDZgwZM5XNJwHMDwf4YYc117REmnaH7jsiRMdgssK9gbq1sBzFbY5vn02ZzzGzTnBGwvDRg48oSA9xqe482UhCKerMfL4bl5/cTr6jvEdWt6JM3E7BhpDlSdRscBP1dgLdh/jiQ4HVbZcRKW0jmNB9wKDtbLLdBx7MhbciX3rqJC/dVQoo9qrSDMgia/tP3mejLYGulv7Li40UIy2MK3dMHCtkZk2MGLr6ehy6ECWeMgUNh3TrcJ3xNlFrVIdSq4fOqvknaMZDCAfLDAB8Z8MHxodXDa8M@2nzhPHdmA0GgGhHB4bTO3A0kaP1REx2mM8WA/46d6ZzAkFu2YQYtyGPjLaUL/WwvQhYxED/FAf62uGIjo3SOW/0HRnWzGttuG@ppN@EfM6kXY5Q4@MKZUt1jcY1geFcafDWGKcj1vqI0srNt7IcWz2pNRWhpfy5HaqAkMBfXz4QrmIG/GX5gVWymfLRX12znaJGF2mF2NdWV2j7VjsecueJNtkewJ01zQ86TGqWaBu@SwRgPvybqUhhVtpyEI0Ak72XPfoIv1qUWMBUpl@iS1AA93tOLgS5htu2Z0T0Y1wB5kO9/azjQNtQPwUKJbemfhaS@/KljVsD@ljrcAQqc1jo42ngtpUochYn96sTDYz5GtTiOzoCnUQBOQKO3WeJI5AGknePWwtyVHLWDVH9EEp9drlcrpZR7BNo/NWx1kzh@JrMTe95A9llp5S45q56kg3orPIkk4P26/sSctb14ChsQxhPHBB5pfGt01vB5peVqyHTIYGLjIvr8KsZV0db0AL66xeTw@Jq2sIvtJBoCWhAkLGHwq7azlPBA//Zw8@kWAQbuWzgfYTIF13r@BD5ieu7b8@pAUeOd64Z06fQb7xFMA6coLFykEUeLGegabUukJA7dkTi80@9CP7roZdKo4JVDW0IFiUXI8NwbDPBaqLbnqzRA479CXtohrhsdEVfFUMuNIgPA7Of4XB/PeKBdQobcTNnorEEDvNZ/3tn6uQexFQBuC3nLEw8uhbGnlHh4@fnYojT1k5Pu0O8HTEDT5uSbeDWpQjU1KvdTey3sm2o3VNbyw9OFGEvceHIgZYg2@2oiHAC1fmll5r5z0DdbKSvlYKQl9jvJpBfHT65HF6cUSTJPYGrjM0klHvvZOTDJ40@eRkpXc09gH0jp4zXRv9cF9Rkiua73Obrg6uo54rUloH6dQAaRQa4yOmGuZO5qrjjIzu6WxkfAqDJ1Jw7wOTz68t5FP93OxjLySltYiiHZWUxHw2GdmZDcK24YbvdfV5Zo6QWnboS2KvtdtRkHPQJFdbzT3ctuJ/nYshsr8T4ctFUuSbrTWq0FjSvb9rxhRFWYfnE70H9UpyaytrOcCq9WHLOf@ApWTDF16E0EkYQ6sSzDv3kReEIZBuCR84Pe87grG9dhvMbQBC5/zKDn9h2DPdFuha1m3sRRli46a2W4N8bnzAglS4w@cctaavXOMLt9STRIcak3ckfOpGouztPTi8K8Kxj8vbQ3389Dk50j3Ug3J7wGiOjQ/I8YIzei3gvBUq4Vu7nNp1AZR6K7z@aHV/LpMT3e069mx69yIcPYOKQzvVUxvCQhsNZFjm1Fw1VnXYvNbR6m1Gd6XNDnE4syU@OKofxwf0/lv/QlFkmWo/wrciM@sdNRN0cJJAkz5DlXpRr9PDkDR0kG8RwSG5Uhp9bExxOwqbDV4l1K8c3/K3jH2F5Prh5Da/4i1@2VvSu@GHjkQTZeUWgLlb/EhODL0fO9bFwBH3dNfwVuw/Xpmh2wpSuqUgpQh19tW204VF37yexcejC/5rZWs9NcZudjRw2mZ2ZRl2e6jnkjxBre03/f3tFLpLt7f0Hf/IB7OvTu9iYqxM6In@drUHpTRnK72ACBqDCT0ScdN7eYG0DTyvYfdNpuKRPHDG@9R2i2AWnnhevRfBHD2cjNbnGGgjfhvjOjlfCvgCZGbnwiMP8Gjcgk1fIfvj/rjV7ut4WhJODKKm00enu0HrenYiqZEUF7n47GjJGQ@Pjp@dRNxcYzpdJ/QK03Uy5EqfRapPT7NLyW7VXp6vQNb680bAbgA9Dt9r@SBG7D45uUkSUHwbjIdW4POJbi9mTJcqrOuM6UnDlZ5HsyndRrmypgdsF9sqP7ezwnlJsIcB2TQhbU9qtVAdU6u1rlWeGp/RtQdgg8iYsSUMqK94yZhmB0EOaZS1HdU5WzA/S9k9GQ1Me7rSa7guDt1Fmnjtre4Gu@TEci7I41Cr0DryoK4Grp8b9jritOqwolDSbufCtGss1bp6YZ9R8V/rquTBOkbtGs3ADRG3UROMf9yRDgLLp2ryzvCfnATB7w67Zzk4f981J8O7A1Ow6fTdAd1byN91gObdwfCrI2cDx7XvDho0p3L5gfGBmdj44JDDWcf5gDy0e727A@17zt2BnkyssYkyy@qgT52JhRoEVvntu/2V7rWtWqMhlsV1nqjQ3Ru4yfX@uC/SmXggA5kh8QwjCq/N8ZJj0Gaibqhf3rBF20leg/uJQ76KmuRXoOLtB9bRJwfrwi0v2ExwiZ@eCF4Y123qHc20Ozv5W7NPLR/S6WxzeGvYhcq/Q9exmS25bnhcqP9bkdIj3TLvJGjBhgf1jq0POKAxf3Ku3U21gEE4WF9nn86mC3FzufQWUzqxym9PBaT0O51k8Ckk3JquaJFJP7b/zPDWT/vR0f9r@0O94wUNDZ3Y9oJgAdlbxwlEZxCWB/STpw92T18cPV7p@1V92F5N6YPvhagPF2rz1jK24TQr/b6KdIJPwRvowFTRGVYB9V9EV@SZKgUYiaNfAvEyviI1pnqEKXzwxOBzLYmEDR02ufyFvKj2CtSXn9hEfdGbVFMFhL26Ihu@dgjw4AN9E74@DFQra9oTAxVasO9mjaubkEy1quRKZBs/SVcmikzTxC9ulpj2ziCxOtm89HU9lMvKnGxUCV/mia9tI1TGzxTKA2BUhQ2FIsKZQjbH4LMZaIog9AtJ5IrQCW6hgxqHwSZKUZ05FV@XBuRp8/Lo8Gj/5HT39PlJXW7OfV0bQSlsG1ILNPrc07o8FN7HGwjO7PMSVMeLBcnRz@LgxLgXlIvgF@GWi1ZdKtqiUPw2xtm8tG1JoupGJGEO@RN4lhr1RfYPnBjsoMS0gnxNM2Wm@YMqMIE6YqB5miZUWpnIqxIe6SAEbtq@//UPKFJf/NhmGT@3iQn7XwSAFtx3nK6fomeQu68gxYPdw8fPj/dJkMFFq7kwu@NBtZRjH4xgKpCgnnom3X9dJXE/ShzqqlqNH8QBMXExTspUQQz9WAM0dAgWYAdVy/ixUySxSeEDBuNhpUj/7evSPC7iUaIkhI0HmYpDstDmaUPZ2Nggp9BIyMPjw0/3jwnmf/8hdUYUIQhyitop/vRHXfa5o0B7XPChUXdIJTaqfYuLaqgJ1LYsNMsgzmnfHa3/3Cj9vBDV3xJ@1yj8PBvH0Y9fQbu9oLpnrykFTVI9fezzqL7O1iAh2oSCT6TgqjXqX8WxwPRM1B6DeeihOtTlxo4bXakWYpHs4rdU8YutOv0CF2R9Yo@ZykFf8VgMWpoY0pwM2aSZZd/r4iMB41sb0NjbBgjzxLNNYCfGZfIaWiKuDJeZdiFBqMVvRAlAl6lJQAEwEvCG/lRParjS@1/5Z1K/QsA8BvO3ffNUfgC2X/JtPTD/MjO/lLCh3dS3ushLNEOoptkvActIiH/EfeQTsjbT6LRAHKqFDQgrMYdQTecU6xicpcCeAtDjBZxE/VOoNGhuUGO@JieWnuE2E6gnuixJ2KRwgkmkXJExZZvar@mLzufyWUWCTArnAUD6gZc@autgAJPJMnQT7twcVV@1oaltbREeZ5mNar7CalbatF9q/Kswo5sQlgMuBDJXJxAHoixigF/NjwajT1pJYlSkXnEljoSr68CwRP1x@EK77SOCJwlAFsORgV8MmeLXhscge/l6z9v4fd7Ix782fUCCAmMSNSV5zteB9NQZQ/OBTrr4yB/TgYSHOtgQiNp8PfYNbqpuHNujeLNnLVR3BF8Z8/uaiDSAgdLk66NptG75FwjiBEGU@VXNt/6SNMYNuymxtkmgmf5gRWO2wfyLUn9Nm2Xl3r2p6TlxXU8zIovsnNgOTqcfQGFIQpVUTVLyyUWRstmVRfJL5CcDxUF1cleQHJApIBkdw3ztjLzdvf3DT54dndzQZkxDxq8HA7pf20o3BDFTb4aGeLRYy1Xy4EA6efLgIKiIRabzEWoMhN8viXJbSRarZAhyceryetFW5fB66dbn@AXTy3I9v5p6W9ZopBv5UOQvkS5lVoUDen75euJqcRW2crnbsrSAJ0VA7zHlEzeymkhezutNkGXtWPxmS1jREV7GxBR2AjA1vNSmhI39ZuGwYIeBCptT/NaoF@2L2uq@yG9qqCwTdd@MnbOFOlHfIeIRKW@QDJBITpSCoGt73zPGpC@U3qpA/zF/dGSI6hCMZDgv34bxCChaVOBxXKQiC5XdvrbqAciZltnmAt2NTGt1oFw3VFjN9C4mkpz/7SmWcIIdKCLT8lSk25wTSaR2FFaG3KYAO4CX5KBDI3d3NAF598gZsW@R0O1sD43AdOwA@X04YdPfBvlkMoRwPfo6NujWAqDcAkQGTMbDrDJeCqiEr/96mkYN45BeHbVg@wUXh91cYpoUB8a0a/aBtieSGaBo9xSlSUId2VhoqhPbjvO0zha1cGtX/BhVikTR/qUUpU8XGdDrumjaXWOaiF/Ek@UmpI/u8YsX5/Ekv6otUYXtvgbz7nXN7WH2C8rtlEQf@70zUIu@ilqUSjepBLhdB8w0iAYfQiyVxIHH0c/bVpFzPxm7j8EIbESiN9RHJDGxmfZVkVBropGwM1QtpVBjmp1tkk5TgQpe1EMkNGaPmtj4ndDtGUlIVfwCMrh6dhdfb80RqSui2AQzTSRJNvEDpXvAcaE@4iQHQjBEKVOwVWxCIGZAjlgnEVkDhzjoD2HhRXXYrvCm32ukK7AO4oSWmtTuk8hnZ5c5R75UKvsVukwVSwRa301yKEoA9gadC/h6wK6vmA1wBuKvyMUWhPwmxYvRdGMsI498jW6QnVhEG3ug6I0ArIWu9M7AxTuxb0NfAf6gXH5@etAqJiWehJrh@q7ZxR0C7JsmoYjnf4UOuqm0FDReYRLdxxgNdfC2mOo5VAV7QDsMf42kxqJo8PWYB8Kyt2ibinJrq/cj@rUAIbM4APgn6FsBONSbHMy0rfBbTex/@tMYMhuJTUU5a7nn6XhOrsBDqeRIjtzbbAjCZl2u7mzqIEWN30wbIJNLqey58XDQ6x72pQbPE41kJSl1eXkZP0gdmS9zJC90TTX/Zjqba3ntzXSuKcU3ZyMlXxffTJt8sZo5azbqTXJ09Nm71rskPz2fveFJIwGy5t4zXsnysXKJXG7ntdhZCb/PDuLNGXkL11mP4J@a33YjZh3N7R6IsHGexBoNwLjCF3hJqseb8Kfi/iu4mOBfr4k1cbv57l2yruvj6YyYpjnyul24nQFwkGryhIC8fB8oPYsgkQZ9UwkKrtxwCsRu1@j3J/v6zJwcjHfEglgU1cjswtaTz1/4V@XF8@eEPCfPn789XjMX0UynE4JQp@bpNb9yS8/F8Avrf/rjjXnm8qi19affGErGBr6e4evb8ydoPlFy9zY27j14kM1mVFVl5qPPj35@d3c3@zCTO6rntrOCvLH1J3@8saGqW6q00fQ8pRmvn519xqtylhf/9Ifx1tHR1zyvpv2fX39XU/BRgMc5KQCdgEsjChjxWYRbQR7rQ6/Y2xi0ciU2o79WLHC/3CBKbbvw37/77E1sHKup0gsX3uPYm1i@GGNGMIBNC2znsVpsC4Pl57GZVK1WwVj47/8O4tc@ATjoM9uCRy0XwMrPYjWhSqNcxWp5MCiqCun@31//eiSHjExUKRsXXDukDhefLaj8dhOuFL22ONS4K8iSFISzx4Ox4RCleF@5jxYTLPCyDfx0iTFuxJRiljzbgZDH9XQ63RRbAlziSzpJJCmK2lCU@0AOhHupalVIEaZTWNNy9/G7CEk6pdV3YMQ07r9YumIv/l6ulWAqfw@Aj7lYfmPn1cNaDUqn1bRULU0vv0vR3lUo8o6zw5MMeRUHYaTefEUqj9GrxstFlc9kMjst1jWmiDVhGnSRGF7sGYuFLth5yTW3Gvb7JgndWSxyMy6Jgl4ZLraP15/9hz/73p99l/6@R@//jMqJ7a7Zk1IQ6Bw6Rw2unXK5U6vxNZe/bKC9Bi1KLhfLRak1byRS9VrzmCjyx1fxnBY/ITgOKJhGI9mo0/g1mmzNTx7ttdjCucZcalE334MFpg7w9jFFYstYo@YQa4RcCweDrH@MQ6if15oCskZVoa7kc02BxarvQOXwaqHEt5oxYXMGdEdt1tSc@ozs1NhFBpsecTA3mpoPCuLnt7Yo28JnYatFnWK1IFptEebLhvPzVOJi9brUNOjIUAsyurNR3iiW82VVatXWX5VFDLxoUMMwjrzYeSy8KsRvhwE@Y2HLjLi9jNZEWC0kaMBkKe4d4aCugERAz2D/NRetLi2v8BXfpLZ4UoH2oWqC2m/xssKHnY1O9MO1AT/6hyu04nODuvjONMjNa4OUlZSqSbl7@X0VB9rrlyvUa@kt2q2btbSIRFEQr4XhYOQgnXa7/bbTBj5E19t6R1fG@kSf6jN93J60p@1xZ9IhrPOQBRpczck5RSewikJMyymbsftYNk0tqUX8wKVWLGolVSsoWiGvFWS1mNOKJa2Q1QoFAKgVVK1Uyqqqli9o@aKWz2v5ErirECYPYTSEUMhpJY2LvatvkGNG35okHVyN9J3Xc1Fs@UZqcPAWBGca42L/AFdNURWSgjFQhgcwftQIcjn@FIUjMWDmLpvvUvV3KRKtH8HPJbzE1k4zLczndTBXKv5/qxYaK/RiJihcc55Ob72sAY/zslZPA8iXPkhRIBSo2KqR5hb1ClPzk/P9t5rAJgnprfpW1dmjt0g7n9AEkFtL2dzZoS1pB2LWNqGTJ9PpTUHYwJG37o8/EBjbm18egNRMkHjWieedHQKF/xlvkCaBkMy35rV5fWs@39qC/xZ9zv03uM63bvzpa3GtCbPwbyIRatSlWkNq@ISoCXZRqqGLKDXAUIM3hKtrarGJQx8yMmLzH@dfzCyeoQtmuSlCrrlYiqRiqIVXi6W42Kv3X/xveDfef/F7yJQS@BllLnZJCBeTUijSlphkCw9iP7HJE3bZYMY7sKILOtSeoKPNHjaueknSK5GU2cJCQinmkyKO7S2n10LFPiJ5BUFvEFbCq8U830orM5XEtvh8gdLSn7txxePxf/JKLRXibDYINdO88jzvSSSXi3xC4IoqK4JyVWMfX2Hfyfq5Vdc/@bl1Fxe7KhGjDPhJEIYYLgbtKCZJglDjYrWtIR5dwvUYAUXf8@pnwvNdAedq9DFdbeuweYjq4X61VKqhIGRsHtG@k3qYgqcC//0NKAVp9CBoo1ftDIHJbvS0nNrAD3XEhPYb/D1@iz9y2sHf8Rv8kdO3@Dse4488aePv9A3@dtv4Ox3i78Eb/D15i7/nffw1vqJpSoXfvKSISSslZb455SmCKjB01RpfGbuzMv3qHK9uqyC5@rNZCS1bSsYaXzGmHWM0LvvTjniOzOiMK3q1VGlXVT@ovwkefUTTwxMFuB7lzzKWVZLE@VCtlHNcAXdswgMc0lpJcdz4T77zjW/Eq9W4EKcfDMuCm9DGQG0aCKwQM8tygh9ihvxBdXtevLIT/0qdzjTkSs06ejbBg4tVyaayqciW3JGVttIGg0lkl8gDeaB0FSqRyQaRZ/KMyENH6YLJgJ8MJlPuEblPZFu2IRj4gmncksdo6sGrD78eAHLhZ@JhgLYidwgkZCFPSr@NrLQwpnzVanB1Eif8KwNEalERZTFvNvFzbnX@1auGlGqqpSIRsVmLrfqrRrzJN3j8xIdaypL2zNhovOKB85B51vzRhcQ8D@T0SkxqNCSGeEAXrcn5vNXaf/qw1ZJwJGwQo5beSQOB39mpAsH3X9uxWmW7UabjRTBmxKSt7UZNE9CcT8NooKJb@kteC4jwrm3QkjdfXbwCySZxgfLNxTm8LgLDiwY8Wkzyod7SxYtGxEoNknRxwUKvgLBkWDAy0T8Ihv9Qf/Mf1//Jc5IkiXozmbicbyXolcRfMnk5v5z7z1oykfAtiS34oQPYMcrlvIZGGugSTPVEspmcz5kbPBPJLQawBsls1WjcRTgYT2JhkjRZ9kj8/b4haf9qxCvkFb@15XauGhXa/bNyicT4VxWiL3b@NBpTWU4CifI/PITr2PoV3V6RrNCvzm6260rzT35IPy61naSBctlKRUkRZlGzaqWSDWyFYqVSDCybiUTp5lWTt5U8CEbZbDJZqYBlOwArgxXi1sm7NKmSBjyb9@@zRIrq1VUAU8vm0zLuuKpUgpRykKzh6R1Gr4HlPHxGP8wEZCIXI0gNiL/1JCHTL7shHY/zZf7@/UTXwAMj3e3d5P37akm@ugpdRiNwUpacWq2u6bZa6K5dXfEtnu7WKeXALhevrhS5lFbiJOm4iaf43VlIKyEo5J5ao8mWgEir2QJ4@znIbW3ls7VaPgsu@SJEhEIxEl0hcT5e4WOXtBhKscAIGF9BZxKDDg3jo3c5j9GaJNlcMgHELwmc4zyGPxfpJBufcrlkJSvLscs5zwIrpRILnSTZfKKYLvm/6kaS1IA7Yj9k8bR0NlVI7QCzjD9vuupCUlq5NKrKvHpplHHOf16BEd5zgLdBvUbG/ftaCVBTlCsNzqe/VRiBkMGCR4OLx9Pk3n0OlT258XJlh9aoUsyRWLzCHIU40HFSBNxKaiqnFBEXnNlDLWXAJHBMUNsgG5xK3/jgSoyX2kBHEHxuUD6uCxfpkjbp40X6KFASk1j0IhZh/vTZ6YSBHHb5vqGVxsUrdDHCi82zazmNtU4Yeo8e7@7tn2bULYHE1IPdvYx68vxBTEFrbmGn3hraj/d3Hz57DhGOHu/vnux/fPjp/vMjcPfIxeIKh4VgcAgHiYhphf2CvOBeu291w9CNiWG0LiaTizfktWm2TKhLawKFcvou8YwWlGWkL8pVgbtjevrr17o7ohd5/4Nvvf/B//D@t7/z/re/9f63v/eTL773Lbh/BPd32Ps7/7aUw@dPvvgXv/P@t34bHP8z3H8I949/8sWvf53d1P5HcP/XiNsf@XckHLs5gPVLP/niuz/8yRe//H24/5V/f//m/Ss/Xn1/75vrb4z33d@5Pcx3/h3cv8tgBWG/81vMDd83wv8WC/fL33//a/@e/f/E/6Hxt9//2h/hw7f88@//yX99/43/qKrFP/k377/53fff/Mb7b377/Tf/qfr@1/@NIkcfv/P@e7//l3/wu3/5B/8z/f@IPn/3Q/7vv//P//x///P/9Od/4N8/hvvfg@nHf/4foZ/@ze//AP/f/f2/@cMf4P9//dd/8/u/@je/9L9Qw28ww//zr/4te/7Vr/yXv/7Nb//lj7/@17/647/@jd//y//jl/@vX/8vf/U//t5f/bNvoONv/Pgv//CX/uIb3/qLb/7Lv/jGF2ue37r1@cUHuH/xD@Dy4fn8EDgfUq4v6/LFz5Sfvws2FqlAO4HW/Yvvf/0XoIH/GiHvv/UjPBAM95r/j1SFhvkRs/3/wKDeLDP6yGCC@1fff@s7iKL/CVAE/xBf3w4tSz7M8u2FBdD6mysi/eJPvviXP6S2mFGu0SUlHLqLajGdAvEmVSr5w7e/2gRRfmEZWgjAT@nbSKGW/L6NtO39D77@/of/9P0PfuP9D34JB28hW8rsZgTljqU6CJj7gHAYMP8h4TDgZ5B@K01n6IT0Z2Db@CxX1Gzbrnz22Wdc60rCk@c7V@Qz@JHPgoswLzyZ7nsFfuiOR9UJuNdfvWri@m7ETVIYcEllb98Lt99DSoJ6L70tKSrzMq6kTRaLVMBBK2qNSNalXi9Vhh@BR7mcuswI2w3g/GjUOWcERVJ8qBsSUfSMltJ0CChlWThStnfkbLqQ0nWQY9MIN015oFTAkeU0Mk37SU79NWB0h0DTFDVOCZvYn1LvKTelS8XwLxBSJBohNvtXOJKm7BK98Au9gZEa/HjBMjM1cjlIJr1YNqAsImFcWoq50MVzmm4WRJI0hklPQfYGA6SQBq8HIAFUq2mMWGVZBCsrTK1IaFbS6SqUG2OzOJlWEUFMH1AoELOaPiatVHXKIqYRXi1AR5pDp2NeUfl0sfoQEqxOHxKEhcAp2FevqrVidVpDcO8YdtLT9AOaJwRWTU9r78BepTAhHhd7@A6yUqym07UiJoiFZNWTabFKytHC0bKnSdqvA3jjGYjtHULu8UqRZysmG4gwFhqf6UVoDAjBwb@RTvnFof/ASO8URfgGTcpPhTD/bcojbzO2GQMAXEEQRZHAjZsStskOeE8ZqDRNFl5pBiFNWwRtAaEDwdmkNJem9ZumFkgfnC9cc2wQVc1WQNyoEHRyOxx@25huc5e5zSnusbwkPossVwidkpxzOoTJyhp3eaX7RxU2dTIHpzyHIViaqS99YWYRWZubm1ysxmv8M5FWjSQR96xMD5zgHkwUnMqEz5d4dDbo6ZugrBC/guUj77/@w1hWLsS4zTguZsYJS4HcS7N7ZydF7gE@6TviNqUHOoS05mSdGIO5lU7zKqRWc9LcyxTiLpam0K44cVqlK6hpLpMhRKzG0I88e/bMzxJ1eFnl0tCpVE1BOy7kTSaTGMQQxYyYyfhvkb6pg@gbROrrv8VNRCuJCm8KCPTo@O7dO6hwup@tfAhiNPG3tqnZIvUEB6ZTzLJmwQktNVvi2DwDUfJZQhK0auFKEjyKlIA2muTYOQjWToIrEVeLIAxjSEC9mEgFex3zChIXduaLHjEnucKSFXITteK0IZubxjX78LAVy1@imEsGnnvPyN6zJ0/2n56Omk3C4QeGJ2OjNXKdjuF5CfTbffqQtUO1lE/G6nXEymlZRWLH7ZdlbI/pw4fHhydlwrDkV1CClqNCl7t9vJQULjYavdiK@VvDePxKrMOf4LO8QEVCLQEhTsZqXKxjoHQF7Q7/cFe4J17/gTMlCTnD8xklj9JuEpdtIR8/70wI6jBnCs@gf@NBGnFri2KAq10KkcUhdKiRY5VjBkGhBqKVioGhwAxKIY8B2PZLonG1k/1TAH36jCiqLHK1z8hUxKwJc65mVS3D7o8Hm7iPkW/IfKT0m3U5gz9V0@CpZPMZJVdobmxYlwIm1KDt4RI3pM7BeilggT@Ci3AfceQjcIJLmBMOt5kSf7L98FnF32iJikUTbLclr@Sg9yY5XDDw4XGjyAWAoaMsr7hxsY3PPx@TWm3/6UPh8ABnDaYDEuw2FMyuOBBpm@hOXIP69gnpmp@a@K1gsWt6I0ufQS8EhMTm83kPIB0eELWmUiuL0cXnvENd2mCeT3UOKGePi90PZke4wv1yufpOyRYgQ@XyO01VOXDgUhJub9yA1kP3hqQk9uPtalaR00qwyECSPM9XPMiJphWlFBdTeB5emqZxtEMQrmxwhO4PeidXq4JPfLMK3R7E4Ueq9GlVDS8/7PTeIqwms7DoAx6kP3aJHPgVmJ9vC@g1FAW3ROL2dq7iUwj5/n0N54a0rByWnVDMkDnU4qaW1bBmwA1cm7FswV@3gvI1Y5xljEm3CuZYAwvMOqcS4wnakHhpRZmL1WPQVbl6s179//7XrHPN6T/eP6ClXq9yU6B40dt3xjD0TZZ@HPfEebb4P3s2jFpv/Q@fOU@eOUMH/jB@PUFyVFn8K5Ul6@1/nxIixanAAMWN8ViUDL@snOP@0V/Q3WmTZiumW74@9Brd2FtXStnmPnSZOmluBarSaxB6i53yJqijrspjgaWx6Z/8rnmG1RPxRGCV3xrVNFnlt/yPstSCiLVutet0JrgFq9IVTds2XDxTziJks3zFsVG9cTVYloQBKHnJ9asXVO8NZ1T7ImrMc23d4rpi2@nORG88s/BsneW41TjIQ/HAYwHdAEYZ54S3NS1bhiKJI2e0zam5QrquyMBz4K0UM2pmw9guFMpdsWMZurudK@eKmS4e2/MXjbdzcrkvfvbk8aPxeHRs0LN829kSREAds6gNcrtYzuWgxfJ8uk6TadblpshGImFjA2i3oXcFeOOasieoxSZE7pputRqPb2uKKihlTS7OuQXiAOcDpZaVs1sSvEF4k3CtGkZJwCkiWdmSRlh9YIQgOhjbYMxtSW0wmmAsbUkmGCc1TZG3pAmrRcRZjcPMpBFXGazJzEC59IePsu3YxpwrZ/SMeUlRW@71evPUZXph4fRLgdkA6XNBz7QvQ2tFiIQrk0lGMBee4KL3oA4v/SX4Mq/minylXlnYC3m@0pxzO0Oja@p4LrAhX96MlYdBnUGNQUINws3LruOMy22j57jGIqCm5IOALEM3A2T5eZhcQ8YUL28ml48Eml7ehJLN8fMwVpAtbj6HymT4ht728iUXSx1/qtVq0DAuswU1m8vmVC2fzxVUYERK2XyuCJUq5@WcqkIvzJaKpcIceoEkvYvRLwmTvcugd5Tpt5QSepkpA683SfLdU9O6LGoC68eJZAWGsdg7Lnbv@FO1Vls/n5EAxu1TVahVtVwJTBqaVI0OeqoqqJqgKYKi4f8Og4r/Dw@vwl/FJ8TSVO4UVQQ@BX4K2EWbPEZVY2OHnDr4sck@eWB01oTYG@j02MKe63je3yHMA90@Y14PTaaXP/R6pOMXd72hOR6sCfF8NETtgob7DwZhf9iGDCL1ZAEewMO1HGdVgAJ5frSmlE/CL@EAMtincCD48eHHj04j79P93b1HXJ48ePb04bVXzg@UI4/3D05Da4H5BlFzIYif33/8@LrVf2WfPT/uTRwXb@7g2fPs4hE64al4LgvXcqDQmQLxH2ilwgmwkGQDZLPAoHB4lup@tkTu@8ZcfmGU0fiCHfk3vfBsD9P@UOZOAz0AOtVz0jZIhymRxNknquDZFx@VQonjRsR2LkhBJl3HsnSXOL3eBjgOdDzTbKBQZFnYEjHpC8e1uhdm19gAngbSKIFs2aOZ4B4BkOGkQ/UTAfeKnwuAQdAmuKjbtiYGmYzIWkd4oRMaXbM/gCH7wgkCcG1dJ3B/2QviG9FrfLvDmKVB3W74WDeDczGuFOP5PZ5/pI/1imsUXh65MGx7faO2P4WmCh1Hd2eZYkbjxzn@gJTtl6k@LgxazgjFV29UT02ALd/YABn8r37zR3/7x7@6rTbkPRmnNJ88zqozYC0UqdKuviNKfti@qr0k21lnhxBk41EUTLWMWLFfBemZlL1cXtnGMRYGercqp8tAC1FGIigDESrR@KKQSCVqtVTMFUuaWswUS8VsTsnnchlFzSiFYqEEoGWlqOSLuZKSKWZLwOtkS@CbA9GWCVJSICRJqTKAtTvWpGtsUaFcHID0zRb/yduEniQxPbRPCG9AHJ7DCZMxVSuRMqswohJFJlqBAESddEjs4GBPPjjg@Qdowb1PezLPd9GSK8py4QHPG9Rnr4h8G@@wOEXU3cyPmUWWH0DVTBgA/OwRzw/Qsp/H2WyeN9Gyt3twgOn00KJifAh2xnyYxQosBQhmowUkOQrgTQgNgu2ydLI0o/towSTR54D57IEfz38cZAd9jlkwBuBRUNLdXZ4/ZJbdXfTZo8XOsYx@FS279OJ5FyzQY3i@D4a@C32V59tgxH7D8x0wdWY6uA3BhF/Gscc6z88YehBBPD@lofXOGc@3AndM5lM/NznEbplaFFbqHWop4Y/n1SDTGEwLLRrPZ0NLFsr26NGn@mDcNfrsmrns3YGSPnqk6eZ0sn/Q/vjjdr/fdme7@x8fo9fe3iNgT2YTt91v@xHbLbgciLX3SNXPhrPrF5T6sNUq69ZKr6@2WlndvubVmrUMzCHEegM5868@JjRs7YHX3qPWjr5qEwcF2EKSMYR3G68HQ3g/0NvMK7ioF31P222@gs1fkhoJDqUS3I@B3fEMSLCdGeod16mgfVolcgY5nVk9Lzcr1IMMQbqQK3P07yXwqeOkZPJyVp9W5WZ1Wi34uyZ7Cb4xVXMmn9kYbiulXHlD31bUbHpaRs02Ti9O4oKyTRLK/dRbknia3FZB0tjgG9vbAl9Xmtv5wkukTGV8bKtKsZyVVZJkVq1QhjhyXCYEH8l6obldyJUXkQuFtC6p5UIBuDnAzxh4gjbODLZIInFh6GfJJGadzj5BeWjByYwW2qz0EtPMtMoySWbJyrSqVNjnIYh8DVoi0cVvEU06qIKeMKB9ADjdlsu4ASjBK6UiD3mQpEQSiNB8PmfIucyCyHJ56V1eNuYhaZTAtJjie/G107PT088oP1nzZ8yOXANpXMW3fvxoTzx8Ftjw80LiAfK5jivuIW1b8mEMb@B0CtKL@AhGaJAtAzc8Z@w6lrhPt8QCsxx4BBoORV/Vv3j6aAnOycC5YCmjmpYK1RdtdwyCX18yu0Sv1sCkd0mC5oroyQvKG7RqtWqrOqSaTKCIQayvEvppogWYQ4/lPVQeQ6Nf4tlb36NVlecwRE1jU4DTqhJBeTV0uq/UdKfSxY8uPag@wMiVFrzbFaNquK7j8iAY8pXetl2d2J7eM44MF9UiHT7bBE4FD@QmesRIbpLGPobeQwFnLtRcYi9y9nQyTOhCrZ1cdsKJ49ABkZP4WlDoS3pGvFXl@XmlVyWJlxD0DdjdTZLoig@S29kK4OkBaSXBSX7Ve9UjKslnK1SOSSAs6HAUP1huPVmtfRUYLAb6jJTLkBu/os8AKiYGgKEOqI@eHJnzSqdqkYRApkmKo2ylX61j9Ct8bAnACwhC/arJ1QThBVeDTl2ZxfSqN2nTz/URua2ocr4yBTelkK0MoHb1l9OKWx1NXKNigdWfRGan4fUK4BRQB2DeXiXe/8LXk1tCrsrcKhTUFTISLbFVnVZsVAAO7aKqVcEjXc/KmVwReIxcIQOMgZrPKPmMlslmhAK6AleQyWXAEeQn4F8SVoInhM/IU1lUMoqhZBLyK7P7Kpk5S8hQfoq0ZGbs7NuTIUEXqCpsm9QObz2ZVlOAmq5D9C2BNlUgJRUsF@B8QEZmZkAhHRu6xSIkBaKlEtZmAgNtnk5G@/Vmubw/HX0NvBLCm@18uiCn3yaTlcRGsuoZb7hahash2aGlHm1Aw/Xn14k3GdahksGkFNRyvd7GIhbkjCZrUDqzddXf4mt8MyNv5BWoojmdiVIIIxvR@WVkixZuoxby9ZYBVaeU1Aon0mldragKJSmXyslsbpnF5EY@2UNMkkSDDzQ/JOLxghqPL2TfZLyCq2sb/GKVhErEdNtjIg5kmMTvq7n8Ng9MHF/mSyoPwRZUlJ73l4MMAxs355AXJVmQpC@5@eV8C0T/r3AneIx7S32Jv8LLJ7vP8PcVcCqBtfjyyfNnz58dcESiO7TFVqyyURErrQpYBLG2w8XKhABxbfiq6qQNQr7s3u/0Vu0lezfw0BDA5eiHPuqkSfdkGibKieRTVIOyTeJQCN0d1lVVa9bVAgyaQGDrMguqqkoFctGK0QNuNaig6SXkbytdwxPEXyWzmZ4WAgTfL9f66U1ZncXOW3y@pLEDsDVFPiMb8fspAnyQQGLnZxs1NZWOH5W1dPxhXMvGzhONzVpamcUlkkqrsx5uJsFNCVIcwqlG6p6Wij9Pl4v9TFlJ41OFZzlOhI3YTiuzkyx5HK0TErs227Fb3e0f71YC216tqM78k8@xly2@WPCz2NgElKnpl8uxazBSv8R1G9w2Gq/EY5dxEovP4/N6vMnFduj5apWdryax8IQ1bufwVyK1bJ4kY6WkbyuUYl4iXAb8SnwnFsfVtrLnvYvRVhUcWv3qKxXaeMx2AgcQIHHmDkbmXA7XmWLSq5H3uVrUnhw@sx@6BwYXa2xcbTi4QBjMVcP1zv7ka4SMAMVx0qjGptWsv2yj1GqCsqWiRskCKcMo01PygnxVYx2pRj3yKvi8/4XvZ6dbRbCrsgJ2Vc2l1VpNSQFXExu9/@L3UDfY5f6nu49JHBeB/vaPf6gW/vaP/zXdfRqf04UhVSvEICQalXwhdnk5urwEnmLO/HKxZuzGppsm4EdS9FIhJUJppKIOhpYUY3gE7qugJGOeEPP3HOdzQiKhSGoypRXlJPhc@br/EqpcBGuw2kqd@HyOT8b2j82cquxsbUPJtrWsWtmAulTCs/Ik/G0ZXgkqp/jk1RUhYOnUuv2@qVKTJJHyO2HrHRG2yDtc6HwnbJBX1RpuGlLwhH2wtpfCk7u4VB6vpaVUnIDURmr1eWXeTNPlQSoWv0zZjWt4aGzgabBlp5QNPyPl0Z9hUCt18MAa2IzUa49PpJKS1O1SaoeLr4JQi7Ee0jJIrgZNJSVBLlPB0h77CUIj@f4Xfl1V83/7x79y1bpqfaaCxFsq5RU19tOfbk3siWd0az@FiLdoggqkVkpiUWUTGkJplzAVtKYfKzSIHRC0JzZy9ix8IPuitEuA3zH7ttGlsi93jjwardEWU0baTdBgKVQUk6GSAVX@l6xwXMA1M87f7XcyFAZJocb8ejPJXXIfoRfwAASkhwr30QIUwTkCy3I6Lc@auCN6ii5B4ynNDLkPUSCFj1DR6wZVcOOPFgJQTSl1MyrLskexRvk5MjQ8D9XGwtjHfQRR/M@KWDMy0lEXE4Y0bRihRAxC80k9unVIuwlpWyxCi7omaOlZgAxhuWORbBAIuI@Ah6FYMIG1IeYWBKgAOfkIEABlSPiAzSbZIlqSXJrpdGWhk3ZOoNLxVJke6IHhMBpC66LeoSByBcOBEwgi@CF7bBd@DQNjGXEMgDAYbDtMFUQZjE5tyCxSRU0fDApgUaWICVo0cv/@IlfVqtlNEloihH9mjnAyj9aDvTqvACyQCe91y3yGoLbfSuAaNjvAeJpmF1qdwNT8ViJRCY/WOcfB/4MbLbbIa1VFPSpYAL@@WK/oAMogMqKd1WGHbFWJohaSJMx8B/LeoZmi2jhCQbcxvSeqnwWec8jhT2PBZyKBWJ1GJ0j9dntdERABBn@C3@hDdZCMGPgKfJjCRyR6h@MgdhgLimJaNHTPdEG4opt1Al2zCU1JYrSFbl6aD3qgRs0SPNaSS@KLxsLQBN466kz109mgut46DlSoN3JsqmSVKoHDg0XQIoBG@fopWbYn9gV@09WvGxo5miOP6qbElo85pkpjHdSmRePi5pe2C9J5gJsMMfoi6Qy7RC2RBG1oVI@mHYJL0kg0w23g0hHHbcsYQpZODIOeZfXKktQHJm3SpspEn5jQrgYHJow8tic9ZAiWLswzUzrFjysITg@PvDLVTDHk67D7sd0zvuJOy3HOiGWeGWzeO7Gk2MojIKYAp50BzC5uQGwZt3epWganVJQMCwV3AV4FZixmInE3ErPkzbembCRaWKNXdAQzoVYs41y3I/il1xXni@fezAtU41EFb2AXQ5Jr@EqxqnFUdxNqe@N8JX9Vql9OxPWUUYKP8YFyPDRyI9c4JyhoczjGANHsBGqmsBdDaT@iAwDte9CzUGfu2C2jcjTIidtNdKDr@QTeJveIpnIYkGku9LUMAgys@uoydPCDqFgOb9yFihHpIgLSFeidwy74oVoev/lh/KB1o5nqM140b7Lhg8NBh6ZVJaxbBJZcxIK9A9szLfoGeOYhhytyspHg0wA2zSd5BjqMfz06a@0cpSVlchNShiAEH9UAhbIKOpIcqrB98fFVDjwe6B77QpevUffi4kKkap4nrikaHn6Q1HNs3ZJGfRM4YUcaG8ORZHjQdV2zI40CuAuTwL5DLI4Go@0p8rPV0v0Ze3Ncz6v62@AS8Z4Xx8HxHL@32R9SlZCoi9GjDerApN/q7ST8XXms/anNzGXQ/srY/oRifI5ACEEw08ws08kAsEy7c5bpXXQrvsc57ZAAHGrRCBxR@bobWIZeYDJHvTCEM0Y6Gnq1rTO63gyQeDb3vEialTAIOQusvn1k4jZY27ggu66rzxLUP4mhsQEnZpTtITMY9qkPGPHrJZdME7g5rc@aS9GnYXQY1MItHC7qe@QubwfK1MKj/5T5T8F/yvyni0SDZOvTJmPJ0GmOxcFWj/t5g5AIZhaEmTMV6gsfChn4cKIwEP9vd9@63zaO7PnZfApEdtpkTN2cxEnkyB3ZlhNNJ3aO7SSTddxqWqJsdnRrUb6ok8zv7H7YF9j9vo@wr3Le4Xzap5itfxVAgpJ8SfecM/vbnolFEkChUCgUCkChCjknmW/f6F@ryqUNveWN@rFqGIN4YkgED93i0c@fjj4d9@Pw8sHxSvGUmD3HhKAeJ9BHx0zTy3byDOp3L7rDQZz51Id3aJqVNN741DrT3CC8gjYmHcSMIfSK4ND3tKdtTUQh0A0mCNDDKBGqQW3sRt56EoeAE4lxjnIpjQWxI43MMWtfOkl/I3VJSC@EtQEdW4DwPWkSoUkpyowcCT9tpMOH0YDymLx5jpjbg2PJ5eNlouTUUBFZs86dZGGVzxs0iexQV6vTTTHp1BVHU0lWM7/p/rfRv/fd6HdoXMzHnhlWJox1xx4qsPklFUIPF6aq2qha/UoYFB8E3XBEM1dd9FM9W1M1D4pmmSH1oAnxZTRunblW57c86R@@WJ3r5yoJK0yqVWripCrDUsaFIakQPCkW62ITwwi6vAgQglGaWyzUxa7sYlfVqggOdXVNsUsLyStG8kqKSO6ra5A81sVo9dQw0wu655i0Uxgl5wheWaZRUoOGORUHFyGO@H@F01ucZOg6U5nDXKB5CCo2@Kx1PLf2IwtpS2hNAQAjzgAgLSQ4744rzrTAK@eTt0RGCSmNjJI3zQYiK4jBWASvi2N4N2EyXgOTwp9b4XmAxm5u5cjJlXk7Gv8ryb@cbz6af@XZj6VsznL2Y8mf@t9/yMdjUNYaoJb2US49gkDGSuZdX3tUtnWORVU7pwUOaXUnlwPlzlG26XvxXBctnnQHJ8VeAFMdxLeXr4XhxDPrB5znqBfDwTgYDx49qsiiKWK2m1e/rBmi0/4AYTGt4BCk67UHYdxfHlOntgan/SgOfQW/vZ9DvewIdZgbx9aT9eMgdhxtNSbLWIAWvoKq22xG/WjcbLow3fQqyeUEtuQEey4vO1j/0pNVnsSTBro3dAcnv4atsXc7TEQ60cUOo9Znd2@oE@EIpqZIhrVI/6fUM9JgVDxIV44cRQGq9MnY5WBIZ4Pe4JS0vvO4gB1YZwp8I4UNhILhkHHxVYAlbcWKd8OjxG35gaeL/vTdRdVPq27gJeVXswAyxPDVaJrGoOxoTnXNa6uTYqa@g@/H98DG9@BmfHkVPo2zLM2rkvh9VT90UwiUMUXj4e1ooOkkt9oz6GRQST5Dr5ICd0axzaZwbWBao6w1nb3QIf7wk7eY3hLE319H/5s70BSv37X7Ahr26mBC8qYHs2xx4hSbY1mXsjc8yJ7Z6hLW3r5jXZQXQeR3oEKQGsuCqw8H8DQwEXYuToIYGcC38Dysz2b4nk3SqpI4B6fRha8@r17fRdvNdtgNJmHb1Tl9C65p8T4t2Fhe3a3hEHQs9Aay1nNp7vKSVJrGQXTJVLmGZQL/wvOuZyvJEiXcwzvljGHjevohfUY0Y4uvKrvVtA5YXl7EduxFhO1PhNuTGCNdCWOr5ajMP9KT8AtzO0GIDjJ7lv20Wu8m8bnvJk26w4yQ5C1km4wQAAYiPLbN9uH3kej2llLnWoWqppedbHSt@T0e3dTjFlcYnpTjprux5G1Md2ees1hNgKUibOv7ppAZyLAlabVcG6J8ubHHBv0ZmYBvvE/Xv2ZWac4RqElJlnTjiJfbrF94DlbGDfrFhtN7@gXA03DcFIYybcOelo4MrzilFwwtrUV/ISWdoFhUFJJrNKxcjnmm7F@@JXW2rq2zNVNnK1NnMgKyVVqZnFamSt0L6J6buqAbdsbXSGckYe1MPzeJbfqvPwhG2K34shwtVyJfLV8sV0ggL4fLlbpLQnm5vVzZ5od4uXLAD5@XKz/RQzq2lr8uV8ywQIYRvfLDC3zXIhzvreXKlut9c8bB5zA29RaWK0mfUp4f5ZUpQqRAu0lrxBFbf6CbOR6FNLGxUukrcEzsY/nE@zA@/yvR/yVeHkfSQiL2OB9wZrWiyplJw5oxpB6aNkykljkjuaJn8/reDttiJVlQzQqt8ewyDJ7U8MXlrDASxJDKJxr0SwhCblbmY6SsmeyO6OjaiUO5k7P1S7hX1gfaLqcfUebjtBIOkqjLm/7KgpAOvBueKHwdnjPomOoYI5zJenPQAlF/Wb6hUejrLC669@0e4r3ubCbCNm@ySC8xWEumkw7Hh3McMHcwzDIJp@JCQWSX4U05GZTg3qliLBX0yLwmmT/rlkEw2IPfu6k5VjmglhFBSDwqHcsoS@YFlsVISmWdpanK4CMULJlDIzxsfeYAlNv6kfOJuPF5rrhuGjJlpUqWXFkxSYUL8HN3Hoyl9mTxWof3u@9bvpqSV9hrcQHAKpnUIvJ18B36@0D0d6NQGyJMVTBPsZ4/lc6q1zfOslOYd9NqZzsQib7a9uYqR0kNKclpdWBp5jfx2oyKD5MPUfKl0gT6lLZvyJasCW6h2/TaQmBBSxhdZD9@XqWPn1evJ9SsRtK9KBilpYCaNBxpeIJp2rSbcZWGz@tipPD@dtD97g4eZTvY7jzA4waMpkguo3x03mcrl3Rsk9iWLxCp5YoSQc7HpUk3px9J3PPRbXJsSx/2mvvbe7uvP9Kk@@TJE0/P0ZMUP4xa7LUm87hAZsPuZD6Ys2xZ9RElDofd2I6Pzwaj8b1P/dyMLBFhTcoA/L0Y9tNj3NOyzJLnU2OXyklei6Ia1ud0GAQZqQRVJ8CUHWm6jokg4dh9EGggRr0levu8WvM4Hlqz2Q96MPzH9NVswnip2dSzGLrGnIh7f1@8VzyPRxzLW4L5XToOO2VR23vqw6vaoTp8VVc777Z@Uh/33qkPtd1D@NF4@27zdWNL0b/67kFdORkTPAQ@xYKS6LodtkIOMr5aKj1SDHlrMJyI3HG3PPl@EPTUq0ErxDHV8zjovTiTl0I/HG9IqTotRyfYw4w40G0vGsPegiOz0jIWyk2bL0HiioKivCe0pu1hzdsbtKNORHkdrH2HURibe3OqG1EPkrw1N819UZIQhJVNhzi4MiywLql4QPlxdkNgArG/AomRQ6K2tgtKEy7577speFjff3Og4Lxla293u3HY2Ns9UDt7@/T69mNj9yXRs3FwuN/YfIckzvhmb7ux09iq8QdBoFRQ8Kry63k8vhGFArIzVVqfcfJdGFL3J2/ZXW9o8Ooy4OugsVo@70P6REE3@j1sL6875zHUF1xB5aMC5S7V9l@@pzlfhb/hhNMcBbP9Qe5dzIGBl0rqOddGg2WDxtu6Hq407eXLHp9H9CYKscHCdXah4vKzrwxwNuJpR6HKbcFGBXvf4mmFx7IBTRXdI9gAZQxWqopj@i0v@88Z5AbV1uoO4EBYahMjQv2Coi@Mqcm6wxTTtjIAirsWjT72g8rryQfie/qwqqsdjySDeph8kAzqkXyAKtqA7Yh6rHOcj/fOIZ7Vmnz4tTfc4WNh9ST5sBnwKvapxkn6jbs0UCdpiPvesMuRG2WXh6NLi8chFIk5P6IadrsyMEKJp0syUY4S2baNcuZI2HRw1KDN3iROPVKJG2AnFHTGsXKrXkEdwjgo7EcSM/O0G/TFBCo13WHeU0/hmayqb5tHSaxJvr0yHDADIs5tFo@k3LbWCsO7lqOSmzM1BtpGkuM9GxO02xDYnEHgj4AhQPnMSqfFMxXf0AWYQUezshsPiCOxb/s3Oz@xc/u8FWYKaKst99fo9989TWQ/s04ydoqMHXXR7@GI1Eo@yuwMRjTGWaxydD5IwdbZYDiOpA/dbAv4xImnOcqNiY1q@6W6kakNdJiusT/oW5WeEBdfU@sJMeVdamWOl7PzRHylYduJ82kSFrs7oBOcDC5C6@zMxyHSZYjtF1KE@awcm5@TMWMi@qeTyo6/KUR7flrd2N78lP/bLz5CPotYkIjrxugQ/4gxURcNDz7nY4PFEfQuPdJMqM74/ASltQ2elpYY5QYYrQPPIlrXvWiuJ2libjz7HTd7pr/zx69fq1IqD8kkEvk8PnNT6earI1Olz2WOlTYBsWQnIUuy3jVffIaZyOsXuM6DXlgnivQhR7BunwqEqUWIad3JeYcki45Hrrs7ge@pDbaoMIqkuKGw@6P4s7tZXdnwiqlBibLI6RoR7RvIZc@zzFJ4vpoBt30zOJLfdwf39EbsZHr4LmjbN0L7LtzyK9fDkmnJgnV3sH@7AaxMbn8ILLXdvx6wTJKz0BJOT5jTX1pMrGlvrvGXmb7jsUdgMPdiByUBatV23ucjauOK35UCng0mVYgODrfr@/sqJ@sTKktyD0uGthaDgH1PvU2tbaM@C7tCojQli@VEeTJfMhZt5r@bBvNc4l0jKrQO4mt6JMIiuYdDC7orkXp6ZmEVgq3vWSAaymWx@2JkUHykAX@jNSAhm3aa1UBnbjMXZfKJYtsIXNPNF93YtuFnC2uZuxHlezSxAdk2QcEpbpbM778Poh9XTD2iYMH9ExrcJk2a5htaJxxQxUPKWChke/CGbjFdCiN7UbAXDe1g@FXKath/nqGYkUQJF13YEutaOdaoiX68ZNQcNkjENBDA0lMnikUzJRgRz1@e2x3qpZOem52CSMlE3OcXNldQ8eNvegpjaiTzZDVRyO2xtsTYHBksj7E7q2GvX5/pPmyh16bFw3RVJG1vrCr/j6lKZolMTYbmcxtjEgny2uPHD2@DPd0KUzz/Z2HLHDItP8e9Ia3vU5DxJObtfeLcxq5v0lMGuIF0YlpvBsxUQVJ15swpmbbzZGTjR7jIvhAhg0AWCKU9XaunrqZwmw9dZiQbOmeZaYM1hJOGyqiZof63m6uDQL61vnvfX58MNmSC6eA3WOW/GYziML2VZzmhsT7hWn72Wzga9Tmb3GfqAYrL15huvGzHt@3E4FVahUQ@b7Nb0tG3k8Ts1jd7DVwJby8WLs@CMXb31qe39/LldbupO43XdfWAPbV2MnuRuVHOs2TPvah/EwIsg3lfAtMH3@G7H1foH@HgG5BEJr7N5zJtvFtxY4qQ1nzE8cm0WaiWreXp3u/EraAPtyV@7n6scv4PVJB3Yet7O968nfXSeqY8IRcP@y6V8nP5Qo6L0jds6AJSFoT0Jr5bExZuahhLSVyvOR3APgoHW@GV7J6x5WRQLD8trT1zuHV9f@z3jp4d@w9a1ZyiyTfo9@Lz0WX78@ng7KKjumr468lVa/L7b0o9fgQv8Gr1B/HyXV6rFtmZ8RMFB/HPSsy5GsEf2WM5orkXJMy1UssqXYev31MeP/CiuYIbElNcqh70DBfiit242jtaO672q6X13lH/eB2X/MYr1fFKecXFhx9oFiUZIyfzR@NjzKn2rmvYv1DwNctBlPXVEMVXQ@jLm2AUDV7Xdl9mduOgAGALTNt684Y6myc7C7Bmw92TQj@8dPU2ma/AsQ4UJGeBbwWVcd2d95OxHdOOCDPqFZ@02fiK/048Z6FUOB@OB5xiHFOCtdTX6KuzYK4xlXhHgbIcRcZ9Je4XEJw0j4uDIfk6ESvqfFnUtTLuTnoWiCOUZHGY@5TL4U4hENV3uY6OnbgQBq0zINEltforF8PdZLwRq8UF3sWDKUcw4gsTpWM84gCEfoZ82oAqWHOP@dqHQ83HexkP8oX3qMZ8T4YN5B3WFJEC82/1he83cfnnRAAh/ILoXAW9xak1L1Ik5e4gby7AjVt24Y9jBlyrlE5ZQGMBW@qrpsDZUpxphGo1mej7wiXIKbSi/3QL8mV@m2lGkt@T7EwSPqfWbzFoyV3KSRv46abFXKtY3hQzmS1SLNxKDex00fLoTUjDaqK2wm6XkBZaLKTkwCPf79X1ryT1x0eo8zhBXtLzM@n5THpB0gWpNFeBJvg0U8XOlFv8kub7pnJpNn@mrqpi5aVAPd0qkEqS5l2/KW9cGA@aUZp5I@lK4cok4XkmIW@l/Dyn9yXlXqZMwuBJ@pGka/5e1T2fYJnJ@yJbP34d3UEhG89qW5MpLi30o@6PMmklKWCzHFFTKSnOgV2VGVRVfQdTixPS4LDPz8N2o5pCWSkbicNjJrfx/EWuoJWMH91pNOQW48zAmjNGLCpxnStMuCu@sEj1cPI9CwTDBKMpM3I3TOGJLjyxwCLXPVOt3IKcGeDUtOkhXsW9yK/4YwZ7FjmTb3F@4oJgfiWNl9vNWQKx0L2Xm0@mrDTBdRH5qBt1wyyS1j2ZhjhfSOxau8BJnaHcwe5gG/xeIidsQWEkxQzdkxRN6TRD2bDvdV2IxG/O34sPnJcB6djDbnilalhmBHwLy8lccB@H8TiGTyp2jROfD4ddnDqywnfJV6h1dInVxzhuSSFaM3vBacCyR/L7eNIX0qlQQe0B8iUMRNKE@Pz0FJfJcAN2cAnRih2XaFxwav2JbGjQmHm4KtfMQwXnGyyAu9GpjYT0nIweUDoeBq2w4JCOFpP240hTO5GOh8z76bg3As9nNKVVHOdfzqPW562XOM99Ui49LFsku9DHwaXCw0fpBSsikklYhYvDx@VHjmOdDbfkbDgPgL56jYn@PfFmeBH2@6FToxmDM8aktMbh6CJsFxxnP0wOgQEXrIyTSdzDHpyPWrK5Q0pXQMyIW8KxL8dhxGH4xfwsx8UtPivzHRxapafN1NUXURsENDdOOgOcDvOBBdwECD1QqBeOiSgPPJVFic@eNS6su/SwEUXUgJ8T62wiIUN/MI5a1DO8k@V0CZQcg6SV9dtTmFB9rW6Ay8GFeQjgekxKAYOAOUq6CQdHH5p/Fw5KN8ycsQemZ4ok/QY8Vmi4h6OIpG9KYO4VLmbhTh18@KpxoA72dg4/1Pbrip7f7u@9b2zXt9XmRz7jxkE5@xhWr/Zek3RJTtPl1HyPPuRqB1QyxwlObfejqv/17X794EDt7avGm7evGwSNwO/Xdg8b9QNfNXa3Xr/b5tN3gqB29w7V68abxiFlO9zzuVZTzEnLqb0d9aa@v/WKXmubjdeNw49c407jcBeV4VS/pt7W9g8bW@9e1/bV23f7b/cO6goNc7YbB1uva4039e0C1U91qvr7@u6hOnhVe/16qqF7H3br@4qNBKxWbtYJy9omLWFRE7dzu7Ff3zpEg9KnLSIeIfjaVwdv61sNPNT/Wqfm1PY/@hroQf1f3lEmSlTbtTe1l9Q4x72FKtQvW@/263CbBEocvNs8OGwcvjusq5d7e9tM64P6/vvGVv1gXTmv9w6YYO8O6j7VcVjjqgkGUYvS6Xnz3UGD6dbYPaQ5491b2Dt41MkfiDCEZY2KbjOBYQaB1hKR9vY/AirowB3gqw@v6vR9HzRlatVABVhUbB3a2ahCIuKh3Uy1W3/5uvGyvrtVR/IewHxoHNQ96rDGATI0YJDxkViHKn3HrUY/EV7ySMzqGM71uTtVY0fVtt83gLnOTRxw0NDcwmTbeqVpXoAzYWsTJRpgzyDo2RsrndlPFyEcY87uyMzfo0k8Jm3tbddpRtZOrnJpwjuadZ5OuVKy02imSRLpNeOyph2enJ82o35ngDumSTHZ@OjFpz5CenmIQfTJuSGint5f4QKLi83m@1qTFroHzabn36VkBo3bSuht8JtyebqNCEeBlTc2fioVofvzDKE2ftAHnWyohwMI5BTq/yCmb0Ev9FSx2A51MVzeB2CzdRTLsckZjlJINPJlRwRPSqvknQl@jzQ7cEHXgC@0mtgnhWUkZxrE9Kf/NX2RycH6QNJZtruKRSxiGY3o99BUI5WwSwT@oz0SRB2ushCH4edTt2RXhzV/4XQwaMM7rC7Dece0Djx1vVuKn4SnU8Xz0@UZWT521kEXYrPuZhUmOX/WJFO6XwojbpmLP80x/3gGG/H5gF1Troo3q/WmpfuDFIdFkq@0awtcr@BOhs73pvbXxges5kqrj9anvr9KvsvYgr0gfOvShHfE5Y7559WxZKABxr44iCSR9pBRLFpljL1JkvmSMp4h02XUhuUPzdVnIc/rRBJSZM@Drl0nZuNRdGVjT3L45X7tzea7nR0SncD20dPHT9bWncTt1l99@f2IetjLLXsdG9I8TnoaJ1mjZIsUHx4plivylP2ZgYtFZIRvetNp/BF@HhK7jawlEwQZmhsjklgfJnq5EHTIKXbAcc8x/Dp3ZGoGcDNN9dCaXnDFKn5AuhLzgDZm6U64167wB7CT4W@GeNIgzUCaxdjvL3EurS5Y7uV2jKkoL27YcQ@yFHKGj8WNW0ID3upi@1ncruU3zdtWL8Ziyojxyt3OJQmJe9NYKGNX0ZeR/Zb9jOgNYPYeRl/@qvmNHj9qB3fs7i6Ix7XxAZFxJymJfep0M1o3@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@UXS2ToyAOPjSG9nX5gnoTTAjl7t2aLSxWfHAw8GG7iMpkW0KXRwyZ1mAwItUxQLsJRz@aeAX1QW86hP34fKT9F9J8Fo30joRR@qkaqE2yeudpRvzXM2pxNMZthXaB@YOb1AthISruSa7ya8ol5jU8umE2HaOrlbJyn6cpz4km7JaUifhcrSHCLucSgmqXoSFTMIqTxQXbbHI9OHdIht/lYPQZcz9UoH47bCeeSS2QvBcondTos4/H1liaPhzEvKNBXYEdkIQSZdlISwxVaY5@otlJ2zXlUu@Y8F3KLfn@ehImNdZSVFHKuLp2Yr61PHUmqLSqXYMmzkLLq48ZlXkLrm/XLsbYW2j22FrlPvUTkVIRJaJ636iOeBK5mTx9xJPe5K/ejzF66AvOuLUKCoShs@JcdVbOMX6wKfgQhaO2vSdKmkw7GGL7jZc@gz7zotk61G7/WsE4Die0AmgVo6siw2i6fxmc9Ztbg25wGg2igNZp8D5/JRIPjxN@RIedjgaXMYdHkjidVqb2JH0W/zLihg3vybnkuuWaKx6HQ9c2UxiPJrUzcRPBO@cwAkzD@zJ/D6d9pCVlHj1OCznZ@6dsj1f21q8t@7A8r7Cc6AOAFnAbUxYUcod0zBeTrMun6zMZTm7KYOF4ovIq8K6x2Mtg/IxIxMcwGYwNMjNmCXYjsDK7FuOj9pXfZh@EIzhaCrdDxOyJXf7sB4jeTlLkR1gKVFT5ackqKqcoV/BDiIfJ9eReffJPxp4Q@BPolx/O45Z5jMAirmO8LcWyXtFeRgkXNg@MWEazJCYpFp1Gfev6Ice@uJqGmk2eXEcNtvwhpUi72ZvhSoxIlxY@iOLnNknkNCceJpVlteyx3w6oILWxW7qeYcPb7Gd58OMQV3bOIJi2NGTXQvo6UrWISog0PWVea6MsPpVvHzGrq3fttSkCVueZnFnB1N2c0Vz4Bkok8yuOtQYjEsa5KeppU4/leDwYLt@RetfKjrme2ebRuuV5txoCC7NVabJ80GbSVid4nKw70/hMMU2WYmxpRjyE5Ss/J2w@TcSrahPjrdqc3EKH62iW2k0lk0rS320Z@5gUL2DRayaaZEgx7nBSup58P2pSw5vXSxANU5ZXTZYYTYiM5kQeLVBTZEqodHcKMfdp3Kfo0SbKod420c7un2uJOm0kZ1yemqSMk0vQE47bcWmT5NKwA@MLuIkTDTcRUonCeeVP@CivnD@Bk2EkCEBoxWE@3YeSHdy0s6b4iKMDdNwmrIXKkET0tGFbOCRO/xOCsVd@vbmjLR6ak3z5eF0gXSWQaFXBuW6CZO6b0@tR84qhzJCChvgcUiQtmpFNZ3dv1Z9tC@UjCFKak7Wlb8lHYzy1QtjQHzupeQUdOK1Kl8yMqOxAaLJooLFAq5TTbijLVWh/0Ug4HtYNehjRAkI@u/hZ0SXgznutlFAbRa7aE2TxNLlltHkqvyFFUoaSd5BfD0VRdXnhSgBCwZjKV8sEAW5NGXscCrDrHZvzMojqPqKC1TKGJX1kr6ipneecdBBVZ3j02MpRmpfjmQ0jPxcIKRbz86SIkM4yP0sKhSa6ubhYOZ7Mb0@agxRiw/tCceoK3StZGiY9JwTkuNslL5UoR2XllzQHc@Kjx14mMeFvTn1WslJL06lEnwTDo3x5OvVpKZOaqXZ1NVs0U5Lo4dm1ZhKJFJ6NcCIV/tx/fDXFdnme2IRai4yMlqHtsxEXnVaZtG4r/Bqr53wp2@gYBp59M9wsv5oSYiXjlP1mB@xqmY8M4Lv9T7fWWKYaTHSsAPZLZy67uLIgZI01h6kezcJK13jaSxwUmDXtoKPeH@7sZNy@nkyMoVEvHD0ulUpg4hPb@b2xrcZWUjQoZnMXO@fdbnF4@ZfR@5Miy/4w5JAAFbOCDqlLaFDEhcHoVCJDAAfKitx5fZEVa/3zTscOwYATSnQedZvk1N4QFE9AUWL08v6QN4AYpJ5gf0ED0b5fVDL6LgNRNDUUcwxFpWESfJEzp2dEHnzowD47OaliYBDMxpqJ5i2vuvEFMwgim3Bnsfti70tqnpx7FXa7A199QIBleApY@DZdYGfHLlCSLDhh5Nu95zH7o/VVeBF1rXvFyGLzOsCZicnEmTB@4eEbfz88rV8N3dzRzzmaVqjJK2jmCvxT@yp3mvO0s/g7gBU@JLTvlLsXDN0W02k6M031egSnT4TRw7I/d@2TyeLxnpim2e25QdT56BbYWQM13WNdwPiy5@7lllyTPSFu7tNVuQMalgSGxgk@V@5WAlfN/nli8WLc6dxNKnIYAOnY75KIEgnlzwlEPgPgEaiHH9ETXrR/ytOw3plyKCIKDoJ1zModFGiigOPcb1V/u3RrtZpaGq6sqFptkx7yeVXbrKltfNjcVNv0von3H6qrjx@vi8zd9r7Qx03z8ZvaJBi8w7nSOhtt0yulVXFvDNba6OKlYnXJX19qVp9vrMfFo9omrvXT07//1//@7//tfxRr@uV/4WWTX45@TjIVCoXiUuvL0g/f1vF@tH28vHRytDQ8Xj5dB5f9nb2GDxrjfJCajxZGJ86izALWV7YjNets9j6jiyoTy68XjD6TdKmoxVZcXNRfY4kcxTJ2sRVa30PcozyhJbwJOjC9lHcQ1K0XTLAdT73TCmGAR/MNUZJwgR2olJezFbNxD3cwSYbkVGVRe@JhnfUixJ2W1JMC7uLSjJWP@nHYxw74Beu80jzHCeg3Gjc1/xZ/fhOfbg6u1INPrnpQUg989SCX45/y2jP66i0VI9zOlWy0HMjlfEpJjxZgZqjiiBU9Xj9wrJ0pcjvOEofsASTjpoIzyy04P1n98WUZCbgWnzoLiPipZIuED5lQZPHLUv8bdcsXyvEtl7lqw4pCU69iuDLrRCXpX6hAQSyGAGnNPSFIZUBV4qSPbyTjqWi@6L52OJoQAwZZ91/u8LjHB5qLlvra5jmzlkKYIzafl6@YG9flMjSjjRSpP0WAD1RkOVnim4TLi8uOWHlbreRmyi1su32a@cTWYRKOjW26FPqbsphArLltwi319b0WbcgtxysqFyXHK1ZVuWnbb@VYRXrn3XE01NcVuHYMqC9Jbd9kJKFHGZDAEZ/9ldkRxhsFxlPUVLdIsKyJag/QdBkJfX01nTrYK8jJkUWE4s8uje2vU2PbK/ItEcMOwgOMVGLK1wmibqy9royY2KfB6ATRAYMOB1Qby7kZ7@chausUxoNOgnSBIbPJeTqeqSmLw1Fw2gt8tbg7OBwFkwZNW6T5jFsFj1oIF0xAAoNPVz2veQZhaZHuEqZI0hS2HELwgu5Eh0eTvs0ld07QpWYoaLcrGAQZdmJKhl8zfTVFx5Srv6MTbJRnhHdyGqlFLEteWBppSDn72gwPs5mh45ga7LGTDJycI6gmI9Pwgi50jom2xwe/JMm78BGg687pW4D6KsLaM9SP2ek07AeZyWnYdcxF/@K6knkR45lDUYo1kqOhPCmnEe@AFemRP2e9QMjcZNwZOQuuu/Ap1uHcFu15hJ18J7b4xUBFSQA6DmDGN0PUu34kwnJqhkpjYBRUgy3/CUKnG5wSfpPLYAJW/LTo/niv6B39/Kl//MD91P/66XePMdEi2cyyebWoD7ONxNJjhWbGop95NVZpsXE1@KmfzfCpr@QOi0UCQqToHv1cPP5aJIQ@LXreg@KnRSFIpsuASfHm@ooAX5xBczGLRXHRWfAeeKbz3R/LnqK5lX/Rh/LBk1/CwiwqeZue1jmjDoHie7q/ncuVk7j4dLX0aLX8iFZCp@FVfhSeY77Nx@cn4RWpEjGWszT1fPo9ww0ZQny7ioN1@nhF7ZSwJnL3JNaXlLQI1cOc63EStqIyBeEJyk9UZnepuOLiJXkCHD5iwe8rYjmTl31BiemgxX0u5s940EM9QQy5Nn07RDgSVgZiI8JbqHlANsFXruNQzwyXZb7nVFBb8N3KQKh7i4vWbNEf9PNaWfMKy@tQonFrpvu09LQ0PUZnhmhmhC5pZWr5nipv/Pjk3/7n3m@L48WN1eKHEf2OF39bXHu6KI/0QG8PzdvF4sbic2Rb@7Y4KdIamB6f/Nv/pvIbfyE4SJk8pz8bjw2stcniRr7KRb4ubqzRQ3l1ler9P//6r9SGJVmxIRbrUtNXjNi6ochW0GfepXTVQCtlWbqcihW@mAUYYmFIa3N6gWHU1erTEm/TLWqriotQe74y9ih6imfDrDGbCslOhrGnIM1IClRRQV5AGhOKjrJsN4zZBpg3RVP9cr@wFtMK4BdtzpFUmZhu3I9hMrQkyyLqQFdqpPW8PGyUfswl5h2VnLEpWTcqJJZ2WtY@fbhO7PB2EI6jVtZKwgzXXiu4DE8K4MNC2D6nNVU/7g5@HRUviCV75dWnxQ4294tsx10cMqT8cFL4nRRBHQyIFoZsdOqrEfXAoAcXXj5HCyKFfic5kzLxJEnLHoYt2cPKxiSmLHLHz5fjYTSnkKrSLv8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qc@ldzbr6jcSpJR8vGa1wM2b9k4VrvAyIs17JBlU8HhNmB30LSnUBud8iUkLgWv65KlELTbzUCnuc5CzoRK852Fs7A7rOY64t4dvlNxYqLpL2rmtVDyEXYQ8nkWdIDVC8cBLdGrOf6C9XhaA9yk6LPWxFVcStaOzqtX9e0qR125oepLqfqSehRaQlpPwjOWNzZlZxPZUsVW5Shs4khtbsVUW2yCNo8K/AMMYumWRgfXEnRz@AYkUS1tjrYqs7vN57Uw8chlKHf2ZGtRIlc7i@nlR9/kkBvU0J1Qb0EqIwEBL7gVWCjT@4HcgKiaMKNR3xF/flPJxr@HBsNt2IMrUdttnTgflWmpf4HYN9GY71IqIoH2K2vbYDsyeySgExdbSQjaHDZech5YqlPhxRZnNN1R4TDQxiVULif7VEctlYSX7ejotRIogj7kSuXVh48erz15@gxRzhZ0a@eDQaECVgHDs4BgsEbt0iIb36vV3HJOPiEE9WyVgD4PLA7gYNZ16XnG7fOld69aLmlgpRzDuuQwGlJcb1cyyBTiKCxgRqA1ijvKue6PlSM07PhT2/tK/4i/jX9AZjjjjjYQ0lv98Db1TOX0xOFAlQUzO8VxH8KDiqdT7LzhoLMPbxMhbF2F7ami1/AAMT4bDc5Pz2zuKGjXVoc0YIjg7JcaK6iX4Th1MGZhBV1Ubzg0rNsXVQPvaLYFMMrFlACdT4DTMNN@KwNtaYrRsUyTEDxr4sYqjhAt01GbnZk7@wNV392eRmzRDkPHcAu2ZSspd@zJDA5kEKvXau4hUVd7u@CrpFom@RmvyizgSshX5uvwAe5KtxCI2qKKkdWsN4zdm8hSZl5MXZumRakfgdccmOXS7aQ091pNK0AQIwj1blIixPzkPMcmWYqT3ckYp@DlXMWyEX0TxTE7mNOV5TxtUcqZOKrAgnMNQOzblHLSkFIFPcqPdQ68LL2NYI5yKxpbA9oMOVmphnNzcpgJtrqNxQE2oo4bWqD9jd0tX23X6c/Oh20fivJm7Se0OwnxfD2@ZY1vuaIaO6YLbG@xbHMLm6nfcEWJmKWkHcamCEL4diQqYph6Dag3djTtZVAfZcb2ccoVYNdAK@Fmd1QPEjh64T2QBb14T1xx8HUd/laRzatZSZO4VNHDQra4bh7YFk0W0loTSELKO4BYnQaROGpJuX0hZXixQGfNO9BrF8PYjZ35PJ1hWVlQkdq@UySyZ3n2WsrcxBarmi1WK@jHm/iC@fZG3jgJOwN9Fy1hjlt4494f44383Zkj//8Fc9T/OdzxUHPHwwpkj3BH4jacb3RyGPbBHI45mfAc3GxHpxH2hzrWKxpR8i0ALPCAIe6QUmK5hLZdI06UOz9hZXo@gpHQ6mNcDPhDjX@kG/@oApnLj9vh/6uNz/@DG/9YN/5xBXPNnJ7Xqp3lbv0f0@JUJXSzH@Z2L9Rdyeb90Zau6ZauVTCbzunm//SW5v@DWvpEt/RJBR4T5MBB3NffzM2iidQOthqN1Nyi4GinXS7i2M/nSg9rr3Y1R4uHTvc8PqtCW1d/GP@nGv@nkEb8hDB0OItIbEOTtbwsT@WyvGiWvMuhcMlKWiLtNZ7RrfbqCStdj@gJSoQ0b2yN9EKFFHJfEtPTpkKqP6bSN5l87oqzyHYdLBMH59YCWlaEZS8d4qL56iCZq2vJvLLNPpDV1uH@65X/ImToBZ/1LTRCHl17GXa7Ziaxl2CHidcp3RirOYB9oNccGVbR5GRkx/q2d8IuC9dLNXZsMTUvzl8kyFEbzv9oLdWDvmFF5caWEdGmoMubVRVMc83yQr5Q2yXT/CbrFv8hLn2mufRZRe3rhcF1pAr0hp/mxXSdtvr48U1zgJQq4AcDsORT/htG1f8F)

Shnap has `//` and `/**/` comments, `"` and `"""` strings, and a generally forgiving syntax.
`\"` works in `"` strings, so the first line should not leave any string or comment open.
But because of [this bug](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/Shnap/issues/1), it does, which
can be fixed with `*/"` (so the parser erroneously recognizes a comment inside a string).

The code is inside Rexx:

```
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
```

Multiple closing comments don't cause a problem because parser thinks they are inside a string. Then the string is closed,
number is printed, and the rest of the polyglot is hidden inside a `"""` string or inside a `/**/` comment inside that string.
I think `"""` strings in Lily/Nim/Erg code don't break Shnap because they are (kinda) in a `/**/` comment.

`411`  `410+1` for Affine Mess, `n` is for Prelude.

Answer (score 1):

## 412. [WALP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/WALP), 17470 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
pppppppppppp ; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"F :n^*giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g= ma:s561?<p>3r=0+@#IF:
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.._#; ; ; ; @   @@                                                 @
#:  / !._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({5b90ae7a-48d8-4350-9dba-2efd642136bc}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

*Lines 604-605 (`#x{`/`endif #`) are botched in the snippet because of LaTeX, the stuff between two `\$` is replaced.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN0ki8SbbxZZVd1dfbvu7Ze6q@@9FslmgyBIogsE2ABYRXYVOyTNrtYae2Y9GtkhP8ZX1qxn5fVEjHdiZy3v2DMR9n6ccMwn/4D2Y2PDsWH9A@05mQAIVpFVfWV7w7EgASQyT548eTLz5DmZiURP90c//WkKD/LUtedD2w1IYPoB6XvWqemJ5M6c7OuWX1Q1jkOoA284HZtO4Ne4FFEIsXVnONWHJhlYdmB6eeKbJumZtnsG4Sohu1Nn6pv9JjxphDjmGTlyDKsPGEjgnpiO9db0IKxAyD3TvhhfBMRwx2Pd6ftk4llOQEOLhDzV4WEwNU6I3vMDTzcCy3UgqETIC8fWx72@Tij4xDNZpDIBVMYJjbMaUiHkkev5JqTgGqbvu@hZBU/ds9yHB48/ugSvyOQjHYia2ObsUvKKQj6zTK9/OYZKPj2@f/@yr0Y@EVyH3L9KklIgB9PAPQou4y@Sg6Hp6EQVq6J6ObAEzAxMuyJX5MtBZShPM7CMlXQg4L7lQenqYSkSQ3egtLAsd4g5ngRzIrDy1207Lluf6D6Z@lPdpnDOdNwzvQjQD3QvsJwhObOCEQlGlh/Ho9D@RDdMoW/a1tgKzD6xLYjkDkIsgNrpkxNzfuZ6UOQhTtex5xDRNKyBhVEiOgAhHplgZDI8Y30OhewEUDmITnwgwzYjbFkuBfD3zN50SNxpMJkGBGjrW77eswFpb0765kCf2kGe9CAMmEz9z0amE1ZmQCcCimOXUfV6Skkzl3Ve7/eJDPUY6DgxiQVco2TViKaBP3E94BpARRSFyGi9Znk0Z1BmUEQDt0aKsgzhh7EPUqvbvhsSs0oaBjrQVmmZId6nnjv09DFwo29Snn569JT4huvBE5wIy9rTdWgMPSC7uyR9@PhemjTjYhG9HhcXUYOcQxGkokByqttTqCHJknChfLw4NodFlt5K10ga2KLKpFAgBWi2FaIWgUmKXAUHtH9VU@AsEbVCCgq0oCLR1HI6j2kNPH1o2SbDNERMZaz8AKLCVS4QTakQraQx6KFrDxioQRMtE61CSmVSLpIyXKukqkKqmESBKNUinCU4AWMVSAJEqgYEyipDtmwDUGex3t0lA31s2fMwBZqEQYoKKQNWoF0B7GoFsMBd0/DU4KwgttUjiTsYAedH@imgF2zrBCWTGQsnLE4JbtLOjkSlI4pflrw/wuSBjcDAYoWUIfkScKQAJACX1QokX5RZRvyRadthtJGP0Si1ZRlOoLwMvKhAScjAUxmZWoYTnkH2qSDkVJBoKggpFQSLqoJbwyQArgRhJSjWUoElM9L9E0iIpaP2aQGAdAc0CnIcBZqCTAIMUGoEWA1FXoBKoWGlKGoE6AdayiUCMq2ikEqBVMoE@FmVCZSPAnRhjVFAlipAj4LIoB4oUBEUoEkBbiuAVNGKhEswW9EwHOJqEBdYoxQgTgHcUHBKCU@IB7VDgSQVSFNVq8sKCbSpRchvUaM1VS1B6ZYhDPimAq0qVCkVqFUrEI5xK8DDClZkqL6METryAUoFqz7URWBGEeiheAEW3Go5rLy6PRnpPZTcLGZvgFFL2CRKyEaIKmP24F5AbgIpMqDB1gDkq1ADNNpy4F6Ik7cVQNJC9GbfosLatkCOKTGHynlaIV/rk2DJNqVEKZrMg1HspzI/F4SoBYLQHOrGPA6EVpiPA5e@JQ19VSp3l4jkAvr6IGXdqW8vkcSOgkqTMk8te@lXoX59U@8PLH/0bklrgSbSM/XAsU6WqRSL@QRT9URACQNWvMpaEjawBOi6hiN0LfOilhFm4sYFtEKyolDyeuZg6gxNoVpJ0EdDgqkXQCezTLPKvD1rOIT@eYlHydNs0k5z6V2kFNqaFnCxJ3IX0/Qs6MpvE2MEykUcWGX4q9UlDk1FHHO9hz28ABoZ9AhV7MMG1oz0bhu0B1kSqFE@GSNrEgHXNgInCpcmMquUEnWDcu5tRY7FMx4d8bVrOZk0SWe5BQf9DtMyk702dG6fYY@FfTBWXehjXapBLMVnxol6ySwwbbXDhx7YBjEKhWLo2Btj32TSvjXCYwUigURAJTTdU1RhaQe5koxPO9GehxoraDx90/MIwoKa6@dpd@tPe775Zoo61ZKuAfTfJnTzA92yYwJoP6IHVBmAe9qH9OarZA88d0w7mzF2p7brTjaoLtB5nyGiB@6ZuSR92bfrk4kNGhT4m0yBA2LOdKp7U0U9mSojCCJhPChwQEiTAs3D8kyD8j7MOsTWQEdZJbFG1OZtDbHcSahWGjQWUDt8jONMbbsGOo9pEK0p9c1TCX2Y@rWqdiENkUIGalWIoqeD3oyUUypiTLdVkap6x1HJ@u54NWusfz2Ksz6yUEmyz/Q5lN4AulZzpo9BuyeoQkPLJWOoMawEsSTAfsFsHZG@66SDGMuZBwotZDrOCVWakSeBNTbBEnIhCpZ4gRKNvTulrDeHqky5VRCp6cMoucQokbvMKOZRSHiwxgKqX39qINcwbcuhNQjUJR/1fQ9EJfPjAo@02zqcHuh2k9DaE9GBgM@RtISx4LPWHmrhBsWI@qrp@GBi@CKx0BaDmj90B1DZzizIOwgsiLrEbVAmIAtir5loiBxlOVag8YlNLGJMJgT8oVOC6nlfroA66r62yFsItEdgThhTz5uT2QRKwhoDVGC4gwHU3rfmZAQoyLhPjLkBzRMKmdYef@ToE67vUjFjTFYzu3zaNgHGQTPl7tOfJ0MTmA8q7ADtVaz4y2xMJjQjlCG6w9RbRwd@YUaMyZwyh0stYwxcV0T/vmv6tMq43kksADAx3xzSBgKtbbAUSWNU16GuOtTM6IP8CRsZ4scEubWZwaTCuvCR6UADMqBuQtOHQsSSPSADMLsTiixaHrphmJMgrC0uFWqWk7AAntxHC4D6CiEy0R9x2/tk91LdAdC4/iQ0WrSIkPRJaJjoKHFD216g6kdshDL5Ys@vJA8Qp5dS518hzAoFr/gNNExow0BziIqKaYACBWWkZYxQIgYoc6jWDW3Om17NPvglk/fGRBjEaSM1CggfTpRiL6RjMw4BTvsqInFiI67migeCrnjcgFr3x2swuzGRdj/pK0q6CKLxJqRj13HXYAVmxngRZDWElgWtjM9Rduh2XBlpc/FXygjF9nK4Cbsz6EknE9eDlsFEz5yOLdAiS9Su0CTPxD1GViR3VjtY6DjS2O0H2BdChImtQ13AJoYtFewrHeQFiDJmMoPkc1mKCYJpq6e4QvrOaAfAKhP0qI5joomme3OGBLIHnTQkNCeW54EwPMWugvVEUZci0noKPYPe76N8RXbQdn85cRFr9N1pz5pdtssN9BRf@9yp7pEBmuQeqB7QiDLpgZ/O1qk/jZkI4iV3Ekg0KrvyAEiBRCjyzACsfOgq7oOgeT53jAy/0sT4POGnwaDCZ8GBEZmmRj4Gg@EydWhEYKUZn0C7pk91MoROXBDgKqAfpQQDJBEDdA@0DWiEYGtWq/2eTi5AenhEmN1lBklkmChiIU7LdPpxWiEjkJZkfkWWhO8Z1CEk@jbMAYLTnNNOYoWBH8gJGpEHD0kKe1j0oDofC6PaDfOcOnRkjmSYQpIl57EKDB1AhhJjgQpiGVbQDZWW27cj9WWr0YDKBjoViM1@NmnXRkOYIkhqABapThImIgbu8wDbRiYL@UXgBaMGlCeoqY0mOQ9GHrQ4@rzgAAjYyjlYkyPGhuX82DqZ9i8XtIOeCMRjqwPVyTICvs6BCsBaQ@M6rqZXuAq2bxq5ipUX41PUVyov9cUC5UMwz/RRCW6EpCRKOIMUhHV1LYtY1NBvWaHvzg07VAmYCxo7k0Y9IP8kHNqKBVE@1AmiRnulpTIk2BwYHvL04PhBI2yLLFDqWU5txcN2Dd2m3tsIzkdxHx7deXbw7Oe7a3DYVq922UOyCpUSdrXTmTB0plJBVGvbSRxLxPe61@PGiKswPBcGE8GdJVSluQGdyyxi55Nnn1xmCWhCyA6aArjxvKTSMBhQurie7o8udcJkmMtBknGUCJYIRyTCGTuQdAzXI3qeTt@@xcK7TNQk9EfK7KnOEESe0pETxRMx8JICFgX1BqxHpHFBF7UcnHpYupKQET0foe58mRiqUCeqzEdP7h8@a1C04eiaQEEkPwBdSvf6ItR5ewqG@DoYEH/gMkhOXBKOWjWldS2DDWOFwcuyJRvwAwK0eESXCPY4ypo/AtrvXs4b9RWMuAbQZ4rhsl6Z1IeML0togg7s4gw0fNf1ojRg2VnFXmt7rDh0tdsyikWzXKgmuy1jmWY/iZROE0A/EOmNHgSd@AL6iEstMlSrQ/KfP7xCuE@VSDAFhIgy3yYiTcu3ObReBIukfeku2GmubYqfUYnHEz4rSelopkA0fGqCJuAPZ1aQkbPsrmQBFlI/ODhS70XA4cA1Hc@gRgNa5NgzeQOc8TN8qCOOa7tDl@xAHKYdRgmC2rQxmwdD17lSQjp6YlZTOGkI8heHb/QJ9DXWW2o@0lhJo5VNP@qOfwZSWilpyCTKIYpKovDia/1UB3Yt8/386OuH0IkoRVmO3TI9gAWJOJRd6DISvtSDCJCQGNKzNoPxBOKV1h4FCIkZPMx0KOjiiAfL4LWeVGKK0lr4tSR97F7h@Gt3fqlqgQ@rWuBIsOzo8dOHR48PHx183g7UYnHluSBXS8A4SK8HupA4YnzD1rrDmiZmC9GloG142LxACkzBQInmj6a@B4JbRBCREbCh1rCp18zH7shJ@9nLmTnDUOG1Y7Aq9AgbHwMNI4Kh3bfRGPHY/DX251h/RkEw8WuSBK18NO2JYLRKrw3X1ocSjQcdg21LCpouR09wdMNfFwOI8ecmi8GGuEB1mNNxRN0eu2C80FlwFA0kw9DTsSvbGo7AFsapctPLinENprmR@mAhgK0sxXmjApg@AW/De1ROPKvaX1XUCqvXiqwWJD4CW2n@ALs1MMF0ykBvBazIXnok7dvt22QOUhoxXUaSIuIOHeTwCfYFNgFFko6dop0fMYdKCxw1RVlBefRmimO6IKWkolwoK6WiBGYZmGmgswo48iaM9cAYCYErAD7BHdBxg0QtHPiG7gzEndAREQt63y3IqtZ62W47HVDQ27cpbTgT3Zp3WkonWydXo@yE8Nk61N6V7GHdjTyg7lInVE16JxvkWV@/Ks76Om1dfSIF40nY5wgT8ugAFKm3LsjrvplsexhBSgZKOyuwEgK/k9YMCNkYlcMLckqCBgU9LVQ9CekSQOlF9RBqDsitRASyHM2IFaZ5MAL5oZHMXerKXtVw0VsLpcYqKTg0LE7mIPIoEAptQUOCogCa4IRhQFLSYAKhxoPhaUYCW3SSEGVo92PTs9y0TydrULXCYVt/AuVIR70N7Ch8HKgMoIOOGx92FFC/sJ8gZ2YaB/R1nw2bQqRw4UEUH8zFGAOdHoiHxp14qQXUQxqLjhCA8IKqjeO3o@VwJ447QGWHBClNOP4BSoxDpzGGkEmIzDJywDLCUqI@q1k6cdwzB7H1TFIRelbAZh3cqYcT8FY/mTcA11QGA9ho5hJdC52p75kGG@5lkWkuwA7VydgcuziaAQoelUYmzYLOZvnRHPVx6Bxatizg1CXgF8j@XRCkhsmGrIQx2nFQqw9JOvCkA@Hrki68hQZ1jXqHmU8UcVjoxxEDVtdc0IGacBCWKkjumAJ9Rod8MPBOpHGHVQtrFq833InpXDY7mVGaydbp2oh0ms1Gnae3trbStXQznQfXHrh20bWHrhy49qhLoC6EE9FFY@SpC0NbNAb6ddKLVoR5lu1gHZih8vLWmmT0Vq2mdfJ6SwnvKt6zUBTAeYAW8AZ40tlGA53ZLN88w8kjMCESeb@Ldee54VmTkAUfg07CnpPNiw@bl2fW0Ty@niPjhgd2q4labsZLt1tyu9M@b/dz7UU6j7Gzdb0BJirIzyAzFoeeO52A7tgq1AQQr9mWVuvUe420nN7JZCqCDQnp2eytSjanM15n0ibUqUy7nQaWhtxpGSOP4pvl1Ww2ZhTQMbDA0LHtTFo8r0D6vWwnm0tD3Gw6Dz1DI50GvtCZT59mGgclWCW6b82AldAwoZdNTm5QGU1nybC5ft2cjOZeEiAe@ANFHwfxlwtocJ0RdiRJQf2WxU/qlCuDDZHqzeBAv8bxQ1TZJnPWwXCM0ra0slwr6vpPhcHYDXTpUxHsNjHRY6e30pIgQGdMQxgmmu1Hlo9NWHdMd@onBzvXjsFi6uB7PJqCsIzWzOWhVlkTzjRGLklv7wN2Ek88oeDHOTSBzcRFCPqGCCcKUVSMcNYGFBy6yskCuUjXh9GBIYUSwURPND1QLE3eiHFqdRqHyJiQNXRczxSAJRCDo0u66EJBrhlNkB/Rwbcr3U8YSntV7MosEyTifdvVKW@ZuE5MTE3GifjOEKM8M/ucDfJjAOJRZGXhmX1ph6PTxa43gh4CcoOSWI1LaxwGSK4/6YvBDKJyGezzk4HMwAS994z0VVUtGcVBLQrDWgHMHkEhoWHsgJUdBQkKBGbDQj5kI1PRMMHjJ/cO2fAN7e@xh8ehvO7Y7U9BtQ1Nt2emM8yTQ6hPluOOLWBDFP/tif3MdQM20AAPmwaHmN1ujae2ToedLo8MXRvPcHuuTUejrou6hJ96vm7rbBwsCj349BGYGy@OnzfEWgJI0k/H16aNQ6Hrk2X8PEpOftKJ32iGymcVk98u8thvRUtRUcyEASUMmIYLUaGMIv8y@kdNCqdxQv8K@o9xESqo6@FABn2MPUPAKgXEham4Ci/0PFfkBfpvNANjOIXCMd11Se25olL/02AwWPHWqPeJgKLJXnoXqDdboLpipiZJKjIgXK26ApNEVKIw8aLVjXBlCseW2Yjx5OajeDXEyLSj2c1noLHgDB50@jbqVWA3oZXAFpaaoORPcKKGim6c/iMG6MH@FS0WGttEYNBcaos2IOjcJFRpuG2JhMPvddqEHDecNvWZWHW9PBvZ2W2y6XY06zxmUUpsYmC7Cyh2m/Vo5d8mMEwpnY7BKFZKG8Sg2aQrDK5kNV4v4tPxfo5GqXO@BBbNTJWF9qx82LlISz5lw4Dw7fbslqx@DqYRLuHcvi0NzTpdbLWBX/UoJB3qsL05EUDjQyg2dm6MQM6Q3GyVlVA@U2fg2n2BTdRBhSHMxMMCCldLxEtLwxXEpuVFq0rpsl4WFeVrYkHqFbyXirR5FSCxhDVGBM3nnFyc5E8vSAu6vFPRn9hW0CELMXC7o3DJlnN5sSvTQT1Pn/tcuNimQQ6effRpS@4wDNxYx8m3CivFWbRmGhRnUJRwcTu4cMlQYAVUE6BLIizMryICUTM6TwPkAw6WQJ3ECYU5QtIvzItlXgYmGMsZEyn35@M8MbMLcWDrQWA6rM6xGdDN7GZTVWEyDZr8XjjvUSMynRwCzdTCMCCxTp4f3zt89kyEmutn0oc4iVSD5qgbI1BQNmU64mQy8zVyq58mtzBOFkcOOGhqYH10w/hQqetQ6cH@gNRRdgxNLwOeWZz/McCbTrnRiExDCxmEC7@MgPIoRpYxs5Aniqy2lv4XDjO1QjprUONzlJPA7sztGvDWyopTx3oj@tDRUL0VQEJjFfqLxnaGSrFtJRuu7Bvj7DVYWFRphBy0WkR4C1IOgHnS6dTZMgSARQPMGyJ3eZ4WBV1a31Ciom@AN6g0FEMYvfGOvGzJQrWT216Hiq5yC1fFs/wn8CKGVdS@uTbZ7Qxt71caMqOBTUcyyf2CmtOXXgmpkW3m4NmwNwWPVm5RoUMXeq0u2FpdDgaNDEUJHQ3CjEQiIRW@sxDWWRpOJT/YPBiNemSy5DxmuoosJxcXlIdkWyWUh@BSCCuMRWR9gmB66EJuHobvKyS1A9paw7Us2GbbHB@ZWauTxRjCVHjp9JJ2KpzyyXhMO7ScE5dOOcWuriwqRdQI49jjE/tqTFwNSy8roDENDFbdRJ0/7g3oZQ0AnXkJ5/SpBx3TD3VhUCJ16Rm90eH9NSmvrmNZSTZcJ0t7WnAT4c0NkEK1QoEHvZ61CRSYgAvUovsaMBBSWJ9VsSAq0QsQOBQD/REILma9LLN@eQkUWeF7uKA3vP/Xb/SB/1dLZwQdBQ5@xo4udN1YUsJgY2GFUfGBXtYXLBujn9qWThlDXTehNHQPsqTbsWM9aroOQBCg@x/jrEZY4lA38QJa4zXVjFHOJiWj@/pE1s3rOSAyjU2wl5aEsaToDBQYdn3KBKYEWSaNREUXKwRzxmaBEiY2irGbiYrWbRFamVm5j6bBlF1Bcb2xEK0Jnte1zRBSLuo9xZTYEvpritzTT6Z9V5icDGM9tbQGdpl7Og0tgDoQzkh30bk@@yyDbEl6dN8EtuzapDN6u6lW@M7Unwg9aoX32RNtCONrUvBsdt0EYoVvFMaOzVyzbHr5wJoYYoeKEi7IkHDRq5BgmnWJzbbem6MOMvrytSxe3AASp2HkcrK2YXZ7MtkcHy1JGr9aXR97JhqMH@vGCCS2sFZgo2g0w@FS2xtKFbora6zbgtpPODcK83VrI66AxtOqNA6@BUJfBbm2kmOHZExt3Vu6rqniSzqiaYRNI9Jht/HUMlxQByZEKYuKGnUdiQ6Disxodd4yIVzXTC@JFRjWOjZG77UIsWu9CHCNAFetbqhTHyDQ2GpRXJObqCSiu4lThnuG50b1YQSmKbuu79HerqXqA4STYBu2Dv34xu5gZXAQBx9vqKhnlm/Sy3rGnqwlNDDstf6rTSAa9ksO491UrX3Ldn3ynF6vY9DQAy6w6/oKneSlpTsCHQxPuq@RQdEyi2WB6vbQtUuVoaTDZWOpT70Byv3w/qESLpZQinKDhIrUH9dRwvtGuX4ieSc3FRB9c9LDJbYJ5zVd7DoxFc69bM4dGAY4cbc@Z/flCo0pSmyob0PCOOVyps@j@8/QdWxibdR1TOZUnQbtDiNUK@AIPKZi/yypFa5Prf9hQukK2vJNmUgU7oltQmdFr1eKlKiy8iVjKLL84SJqYE/NqbnW0HjSe23iu/7XGBkfTpQcZmM7HKnHyQF8RyaGehtahh9ENfbT@HStMNFtyzBvVmVWhdoEtO8Jms5PwfEUHVdjDJ3pZKVUV6wz59n1LBtNoibt9leow5AvK4cqN2hKK/q5b9LzWouJWXi4Rq1RlGU5VGASMy4rD9dZUloc97XFrisJU59lyktYnGXzEs71aVC2JFdBbhRB6ibDngJXq5JjOWYwx@sHStOe69pfpqRAqOKbyy5YqwJd7XtdiV1Rd8L3WMhy6MLHAY/eYNOgBettQtsS@ING83WFnpwS@qDSFHDSc4wTUquP1w/fJCaYbkoF37LFMSG2/tferEuGoyGKWBHL17Y6pqG6PdPW2W1WKlyHrypq1@JbFRrhZC1O7rIp3eVUfOqSUJrMgVlWH6yUkTk26eM1Wr7ex307wttGoJmL56bgmWka0uzQNDYBTCyQCw5eV@aQE8pS4DpgXwW41BDtFBsXs4a@myRwNOu3lslHY31oso1krpOUywELXE3DzLqlc/3QRY2toDEg2nKHkM1VAhrViTn3o/tahI/mBpTrdHzzcNulxm/gGOgHtPZNq2ivdrHOyB05I3PElq7HT5saB9THgG38cx3pQPVwhKvpJpOVVfZJftqubX8IP1E0MkHpuoO1NB3iW7j48tiXwste@Q9vNw7e6QGTHejY2GpG5hT6Jd8N3Ikp0KdNoDYO9LDrJhkaTVL/rCNI19r5wJHo/rPiv9G2HOpuMJnQW3diT316oVEF@vL0TXrTgC1NoesyXW8ovnXHPTH0FMN1K3QKfL2I6VmBMcK311nNNoduzxhZNxEd7pghRUM@7PGDbFfkjEWEe@gt2haw15uLWF8ayfDneDvaVOjh6BHr1mLHNfrKuhE6@n64MNFPDJ@NhqKL1HBAONEa2VvkNfoefu3N1AqWSBNrmeLhXTYtgY5NtIerJzZqVvQ1jaUYDldVbKylVElHhVwwZVB4lE3Jrq5zSzQxTWOXTQQlc0kpSqxL@TLsDtf@0NFBKzFuC/4r9Wtl0dLaTs4ZTYf@VYHJhuv7oKLhZfOwBV1OnRiyhj5Ld8LbJjartoTvWcK9CzrX1Lx2TqV47aQKhVNsQXctuHXhBkU33TiGZlsTn12JMNg4FReuZQJb/PJ8IePNfL0xHRZM3xywKRB03aQijl0PVyKDDiIYOJOOI@gozJnixQSX4w5BqAs2WQJHsJvUlrXLhNYXf9xnCp8/Noc6rrV@aAW4WHNNraBVdt3yohtxf22q@9bXppCzTZUNt45g05BecncBfFqD75E@tIwHKwURExkyOFzpyW4r1R@9rpbF2cjycUVT7LhmYAqrHKvEWOu6YDesgbw8bh/vmrFsQOxNzLXQ68bW3ckcX1ibU9d1w@pWQEdZw/sm03HTIrBriTibjidTP7ytp4GumUqOQo9PqL9/ZgFy4Q2IVjLS7WD9SHViyBW0sLBTXDo3aeNft2x3SL5ekQkobaCEoXK@puLcge75KS7I8Zw1NZGm/YHTnjjQIXgsY2@gbE18r8KxgutHc4IAF@dEd8wM6znwDQXpIV7F/S@LQThez5GHN@v6y7ejb@jfoeY9d6eeYaIz3vIkaRaEqZp3o9XH@EaHi1u2nCWtNMO1oXmBw17bZAzXmQaCN3Wu7RVK1/YKNdz2KlENSOZrh49eZJO1ga7WvkkLjTZGW7o2Lhi4VMksBxSxzXJ0FTqyJe6xDZue0aXCN8Q5wF2lDCqu77nr7J2nc@hAPthgAuE/Hd8zDZw2vDHtx@4j13GhN5qAoBw/M9m2AysLPdZHxGgP8cV64E//xmSeU7QbOiGmbegTswflay9dH9IXMcT39EDf0BXRsUFq/8WuG@uKZfdM7zUd9Eu4N5m0qwQ9MGfUtthcYVgbFALDYCoxjsettJGVGRt/4roOu1JpK8NNeXS9VIGugF4@fKJcxIX4K@MCa@2z1aw@OWWrRMw@2xdjU149s@fa7HrNmiTHYmsCdM8yfekhbrNA/UoFIoD25V8rQ8rXypClaQSa7Knu00n69abGEqUy@xJLgEa6Z7g4ExY6rlmdk9gb4QYxHa/tZwsHesD4GUgs3ZiGu5beRJY97o3pZaPBkCjNZ2YP3wrq0Q1FAn12tTDZyFC4m0JiRVe8B0EkrrBRl0jmKVgj2Zu7rRU7apWr1oReqKTeOF1OF@sIjmUab3UcNXMpv5Zj0yvhkGfpMXVuGKtONCM6iizp9GX7tS1pdekaKDS2KQQjD2x@KbhueDva6WXNfMh0bOIk8@oszEbV1fVHNLPu@vn0WLh6phBuOgiyJN6AkOmHwsFGzRPRw//JnY8l6IS7pUK0@wmIrptn8IH4qeeEtw@pgU9dPxhYsydAN74FsEmcYLaKEAVurGWga2dTJqD0nKnNRh@GiXVX4z41xwS6NbQg2FRcB6ZgOqcC3YtudjVHLnvpSzrAbYQDsy@EWzHgTIPwMHr/KwYL72smUJOyERd7KhJj7KxUCJd/rmPuWSQZQN9yA2Hi07s08Z8ePXxyLE58ZW3/dDDCtyOu6HErezuoFTkxJPVa9xLznWw5Wt/yA@nOc0W4@/BIRIAN/GYzGgLccGZu5bZx3DPaTlbSN1pBGGoG6xXEB8ePHuaWr2iSzN2R547NbDL47vPneXzT5OPna4OTse9D6xi4s43Rjw4VJbum@r5w6OzgJum5JqVNmI5NsEahMj5gW8PcqFwZ7sTsH88n5qfQeaIE9z8w@dLGTD7WT60htkJS3cgo2lBJVSwVsomV2WBsm15831SeJ9YEpaVBbxK7bVyOgpqDJnnaeu3huhn/y1oMkcOVCF8ukiJfra3JDY0l3f@7EqYoyiY@P9cHUK6kuLGwVgHWzQ/b7ukHTCWbofEixF5CALVKsG5cR14WxiC6Jbzg8HzoCc7exmUw1yGIvUtrG/yZ6cx1R6BzWdepFzWIjYvargX5uvkBE1LxCp9T3DV97RxfvKSeZAzqzN6Q8LGXiHL37p2jmyI8C3l5PdRHj1@Qp7qP@6BcD5ik2PwAipea0WsBx61wE76N06l9D1Cp1@IbTta35xp5rnt915nPbp6Eo@@gYtdO96mNceETBTJta2at66sMNq71dP0yo5vSZi9xuPMVPTi5P06I6P23/6WiyDLd/QjviswebyiZqIGTDLr0OW6plww6PopFg4F6iwge2bXW6ENzhstR2GjwOqN@bf9WuqbvK2c3dyfXhVWuCStck96VMPQkmigr1yAsXhNGimIc/NC1z0aueFf3TH/N@uO1BF2Xkeo1GakmpHO4bTudWAzdm1V8fHUhvK2trcdm4BUmI7dnFdbm4WCA@1ySR7hr@9XwcDmF7tHlLUM3fOWDPa9P72xqrk3okf52fQCVNCdrg0AImqMpfSXiavDqBGkPdF7TGVpsi0dyxw0O6dM1hln8xvP6tQjW5N50splikI34bYzL4nwF8DOwmd0zn9zBV@OWavoa2x/Xx63336TTknhgEHc6fXB8ENWuJ88lNZHikorPn65448ujwZPnCT/PnM02Gb3CbJMNuTZkmerj48JKsrvNl6drmLX5fSNQN0Aex/eNehATdh8/vyoS0HwbBWM7CvlYd5YjpisF1ncD@qbh2sCn8xldRrm2pEdsFdu6MM9Y471i2EOHbFmQti91u7gdU7e7qVYem5/TuQdQg0jA1BKGNNx4yZwVRhGFNMrGhuqeLJWfFXKfT0aWM1sbNN4Uh64izbz21zeDA/Lcds/Iw3hXoU3iQV2PXD81nU3Cad3LikJVu14L0y6pVJvKhX1GJbxtKpI7mxS1SzIDF0RcJ00w/jNDuh89fKpmb4T/@HkEfjPsXdvF8fu@NR3fDEzR5nI3A3rXiL/LCK2bwfCrIycj13NuBo2qU612x/xAIrY@GHI8N9wPoKE3GNwMdOi7NwM9mtqBhTbLetDH7tTGHQTWhR16w7X@zd1muy3WxE2BuKG7P/Kym8NxXaQ79cEGsmLhGUcUXlvBimdUZ5J@uL@86YiOm72E92OXfII7ya9hxdsPLKOP72@CW52wmeIUP30jeOnctKh3MtdubORvrSF9@JBG51jja2GXW/4dea7DnrKbusfl9n9rUnqg29aNAi1a8KDesPQBOzQWTk61m6UWKAj3N5fZp/PZ0txczb3NNp1YF3ZXBaYMDSMbfQoJl6YrWmLQj60/M/3Nw3609//a4Vg3/KiioRdbXhBNIPubNIHkCMJqh/788Z2D48@ePlwb@ok@7q2X9NH3QtR7y23zNiq28TAr/b6K9Byvgj/SQamiI6wC7n9xaUb@s4OHT68iZHssQBed/ESInw93WGN7krCdIHwx@o5LJuNAS86ufjovua0FbqSf2caNpLfpFhYAe3FBtsJtIyCAjzaiCDfKwP1mLWdq4k4X7INaQWMbkmk0lGKV7OG36mpEkWma@CnOKtvWM0qsRbbPw00gajVlQbYahK/xJNyGI96ln@00D4hxj2zIFBFOFLIdQMh2tIUEoZ9OIheEjnwLBm5FDE@ilNxMpx5usgE0bZ8/PXp6@Pz44PjF85bcWYSbcES5cBxILdrq55bW5yHzId/AombfnaCbv9iQHP1eDo6Y@1G@CH4qbjVrjZWsLTPF72Gc7XPHkSS6D4kkLIA@gWep0VDUC8GL4Y5yTAso3IKmxrYEoTubQBkx1DxNEwqtRuR1CU90sA63nTD88pcVaSh@hbOG3@HEhMNPBUBNHLpuP0zRN8nNR5Ti/YOjhy@eHZKIwGWtObP6wahRLbIvSbC9kaCcBhZdmN0g6TBKGsqq0UjfTwNj0mKa1OjOMfQrDlDRASziDu45E8beIZltih84mI4LRfqv35AWaRHfMcoCbDoiKg3JQp2nFWVra4scQyUh954dfXr4jCD9h/eoN7IIUZBj3LbiT3/UZ99BiraVi75A6o1DUw5Ky3etfg33kjFMkiooarghVZ/g5opsuxVizug3hWjNo8NbiW@SZunmXlxyA5xoV5jlxjVYclQCJGOy7xXRDWHiDyXF33vjOPo1LajvZ3Qz20u7jGbpxn/se6vhJrARalr1om@u4DQ4buiKnYvlW7gdDZbDAPdXXW0kuHKWbmsskgP8OCt@Alann/QCYqdOwPYwDHcyS0ENFWNZlSfblFj2ATA@AZje3YJG0jOHlkN8xwL9JKiR11CDcaq5xrYrEoRm@kqUCHWNugS0KBOAVzZk9aW2J73/5X8uDesE3AG4vxO6Z/IdePrF8GkA7l9i7pcSVtCrG7guaUkShPs@hzlghHAD66c/xc8085ltRTnpeqe5dFGuw0WpF0mR3NpuC8J2S27sb@vAyODNrA3NWdopnJr3RoP@0VBq8zwoIwVJ2jk/P0/f33lqvSySktC31NKb2XyhlbQ3s4WmVN6cTJRSS3wz6/CVRv6k0251yNOnn7/rvsvys9P5G@h3MlDB7j7hlQKfqlXJ@V5JS51U8ZuPkMMT8haOkwHBP3W/7SfcOrp7A6i3aZ6k2m38xjJf5kHspTvwp5LiFRxMZrSaYlPc67x7l23pejCDvteyJn6/D6c7IhlVzT4n0NRuQyNiESTSpnfKRDiK49mAzA7M4XB6qM@t6f1gXyyLFVFNCKbdR1//LDzqn714QcgL8uLF22cbxFgnl8sIQou6Z5fCal29mMKvNv7pj7cW@fOn3d0//eZYMrfw9gRv31k8QvdzpXhra@vWnTuFQl5VVeZ@@vWnP39wcFC4ly8@bRX3CoK8tfsnf7y1paq7qrTV8X2lk26dnHzOq3KBF//0h@nu06df8/2m9n9@411TwUsZLqekTKp4aEQBJ14rcCqkWCQfeqTephQ4UnP666Yi//MtojT3yv/te0/epIJUU5U@8@AepN6kSpUUc4IDnrTo6TTVTO0iWGmRmkuNRgOc5f/27yF@82PAgyHzXbg0ixGu0jzVFBo0ykWqWQKHoqqQ7v/9jW8kKAR5BqKkQVtkdOyDQGy1@EJZ5fc6cOzQY5fDXbwEWZIiOCcYBaZLlMpt5TY@WPAAN8fE7ZDNoJ3C79Y@2QfIZ61cLtcRuwIc4kvav0iKorYV5TaIX@HWTqMhQL9Cm62mFW/jXqtZ2hsO3cAl5u3PVo7UZ38vx1o09b8HxM@4VGlr/9W9ZhNypzW1nWaOHmGToq2rXOFdd58nefIq3YL62HlF6g8xqMnLFZXP5/P7XdY0Zsg1YRY1kRQe7JpKxT7YeMklvya2@w6J/VkscjUuSaJeC5c6xOPP/rc/@/6ffY/@vk/P/4Qbnjl9ayDtANApNI4mHPu1mtFs8k2PP2/jcxNqlFyr1CpSd9HO7LSanWegxH50kS5q6ef027IKptHOtls0fpMm2wyTx@dmaundZD7NpF8YwICpB9xDTpHUKteoO@YaIZfguFS0NExonTY7Ag41NoSWUip2BBartQ@Fw6vlKt/tpITtOcgdtdNUi@oTst9kBxlt@8RFajS1FGUkpLe5zNsyZPnUTHqlmlG05hLmy8KFNFW5VKsldUzaMzQjQve3aluVWqmmSt3m5qO@jIEHBTVN86mfOk3FR52E9TDiZyqumQm/l8mSiIuFRBWYrMS9AQ7KCkQEtAz233DQ4tJKCl8PXWqXJ3WoH6omqMMuLyt83NiojQDHFvzoH474Ea9b1Cf0piBXjy1SU3ZUTSreKh2q2NFePjyh1czt0mbdaeZEFIqCeAmGg56DGL1e763RAz1E13u6oSuBPtVn@lwPetPerBcYU4OwxkOWbPA0t@hW3OhRFFJaUdlO3ca8aWoVPwgOlkilolVVraxo5ZJWltVKUatUtXJBK5cBoVZWtWq1oKpaqayVKlqppJWq@NF1gCkBjIYYykWtqnGpd60t8ozJtw7JRUc7d@PxQhS7oZM6XDwFwZ2luNQ/wNFUVIXsQB8owwUUP@okKv0pCkdSoMydd97ttN7tkGT5CCGVcBO7@52csFi0wF2vh//dZuys04O5IHOdRS63@7IJOs7LZisHKF@GKEWBUKRit0k6uzQoTi1MLgzf7YCaJOR2W7sN9y49Rdr4hA6g3F0hc3@f1qR9iNnchkaezeW2BWELe95W2P8AMNa3MD@AqZMh6YKbLrn7BDL/M55kdxcEyWJ30Vy0dheL3V3479LrIryD72L3yp/elscGmGV4B4VQuyU121I7FEQdeBalJvqIUhscTbgDXEtTKx3s@lCRETv/OP9ifnmNfZDkjghUc6kdspPCnb201A6XevX@i/8Fz/b7L34PlVICP7PGpc4J4VLSTpVQP3qrgmb2yCGP2OGAG8/oEX3Qo/kIPR12cdDUlaRXIqkJ7GMISqWUFbFv77qDLr4sLJJXAHpFsBJerZT4bk6ZqyS1y5fKVJb@3JUjnU7/k1dqtZxm5jS@7frK9/1HCSqXdAJwXZUVQblosg2d2d77P7fu@Cc/t@ngUhdVAoYol8oQxhguBfUoJUlgB3Kp5u4Yl0Pit4AE/KjjaeNz4cWBgF@w0ANqcONoHCgCjaPDRrXaREPI3H5K287OvR24KvA/3IJckPYAQNuDhjEGJbs90IpqGzf/TQm9N/h7@BZ/5NjA37M3@CPHb/H3LMAfedTD3/Eb/B308Hc8xt@dN/h79BZ/L4b4a39F05Q6v31OGZNTqspie8ZTBtWh62q2vxJ48xr9kgWv7qlguYafEslohWo21f4KGxKphR/ewLWpphHU9Ua13muoIWi4sAZDRMuPPhWaYa9C11SSxaEIrVp0PQFngeECHjmtqrhe@iff/eY3041GWkjTjxAUwE/oIVCPAsEjxCwwSvDjbkAfFLfvp@v76a@06LBTsdppYWAHArhUg2wr24psy4as9JQeOCwie0QeySOlr1CLTDaJPJfnRB67Sh9cJvxkcFnygMhDIjuyA2AQCq6gKwfoGsBtCL8BIPLgZ@ECo54iGwQSslEnpd9bU7oYU77otrkWSRP@lQkmtaiIsliyOviJiBb/6lVb2umo1QoRsVqL3dardrrDt3ncNlitFkhvbm61X/Ggecg8q/7oQ1K@D3Z6PSW12xJjPLCLluRi0e0ePr7X7UrYE7aJ2czt50DA7@83QOCHt71Us77XrtH@IuozUtLuXrupCegu5aA3UNEv9yWPJUa4N7dozjuvzl6BZZM5Q/vm7BRuZ5HjszZcuszyocHS2WftxCN1SNLZGYNeg2HFsVRkkn8wDP@h/tY/rv@jFyRLMq1ONnO@2M3QI4u/bPZ8cb4Ir81sJhM@ZHbhhx7wjFHOF010UqBzcLUy2U52sWB@cM1kdxnCJiSz26Rxl3DQn6TiJGmy7JL5@71D0uHRTtfJK3531zMu2nXa/AtylaT4V3WiLycN2u2ZLGdBRIWbmQsO2dYv6Ahrtk6/ZLXdaymdP/kh3bB@L0uBioV6Xdkh7EEtqPV6IXoqV@r1SvSwnclUrx5NeU8pgWFUKGSz9To87EVoZXiEuC3yLkcapA3Xzu3bLJGKenER4dQKpZyMkzX1epRSEZI1fd1g8hpUzqMndLN3EBPFFEFpQMLx5oxMvxaBcjzN1/jbtzPhx5b3DrK3b6tV@eIi9plMwEtZ8ep2@5bX7aK/dnHBd3k60F8twrNcubhQ5GpOSZOs62Ue47esIK2MoJBbapMmWwUhrRbKEBxSUNzdLRWazVIBfEoViAiZYiK6TtJ8us6nzmk2lEqZCTC@jt4kBQ0a@kf/fJGiJUkKxWwGhF8WNMdFCn8eyknWPxWL2XpBllPnC54BK9Uqg86SQilTyVXDX2MrS5qgHbEfqnharrBT3tkHZRl//mzdgaK0fm42lEXj3KzhR4MWdSP8Him@K23evq1VgTUVud7mQvnbgB4IFSy4tLl0Okdu3ebwBXIvXavv0xJVKkWSSteZp5AGOU4qwFtJ3SkqFeQFZw1w5wNQEjhmqG2RLU6ld7xwVaZLbaEnGD5XJB/Xh4P0SY8M8SBDNCiJRWx6EJuwcHo1jBjIZUcYGj/SuHjEPmZ8sFFzraix2gld79OHB3cPj/PqrkBS6v2Du3n1@Ys7KQUfi8tnGqzh87PDg3tPXkCEpw8PD54ffnT06eGLp@Dvk7PlEXcLUecQdxIJ15rnM/IZ99p7q5umbk5Ns3s2nZ69Ia8tq2tBWdpTyJQ79IhvdiEvE32ZrzqchuXrr1/r3oQe5P0Pvv3@B//d@9/@7vvf/vb73/7@T774/rfh/BGc32X37/67ahGvP/niX/7O@9/6bfD8T3D@IZw//skXv/YNdtLnP4LzvyT8/ig8E3Ds5ADXL/7ki@/98Cdf/NKvw/mvw/PXr56//OP15/e/tfnEeN/7nethvvvv4fxdhiuC/e5vMT@8X4H/LQb3S7/@/lf/A/v/SfhD52@//9U/wkv48C9@/U/@y/tv/kdVrfzJv33/re@9/9Y333/rO@@/9U/V97/2bxU5efmd99///b/8g9/9yz/4H@n/R/T6ux/yf//r/@LP/9c//9///A/C88dw/gdw/fjP/yO007/5/R/g/3u//zd/@AP8/8//5m9@/1f@5hf/J@r4Deb4f/71v2PXv/rl//zXv/mdv/zxN/76V37817/x@3/5f/zS//Vr//mv/vvf@6t//k30/I0f/@Uf/uJffPPbf/Gtf/UX3/xiw/Xb116/@AD/L/4BfD6czg/B8yH5@rI@X/xM9PxduLFMBeoJ1O5/9v7XfgEq@K8S8v7bP8KXDODc8P@RqlCYH7Gn/x841Kt5xhAZXHD@yvtvfxdZ9D8Ai@Af8@s78cNKCHv4zvIB2PqbayL9s5988a9@SJ9SZq1Jp5Sw666oldwOmDc71WrYfYezTRDlF1axxQjClL6DEmol7Dso297/4Bvvf/hP3//gN97/4Bex8xYK1fxBXlBumKoDwOIHwCFg6UPgEPBzSL@boyN0Qu5zeNr6vFjRHMepf/7551z3QsK3WfYvyOfwI59HB2FB@LZLGBSFoT@@/kLAv/XqVQfndxN@ksKQSyq7h0G4cgdSEtRbuT1JUVmQeSFts1ikDh5aRWsnSJcGg50a/AhcarWd87yw1wbNj0ZdcGaUJSXEuiURRc9rO5oOgFKBwZGasy8XcuUdXQc7Nod4c1QH2ok0sqJGZrkwyVk4B4z@ADTboc4ZYQP7Mxo842Z0qhj@ZUIqRCPEYf86R3JUXaIHfvUrclJHGC@aZqZOrgjJ5JbTBlRFJExL22E@dPKcplsAkySHMLkZ2N7ggBRyEHQHLIBGI4cRG4xEeGSZaVYIJSWXa0C@MTaLk@9WEMXsDsUCMRu5Z6S705ixiDnE14zYkePQ6xmvqHyu0rgHCTZm9wjiQuQU7atXjWalMWsiuneMO7lZ7g6lCZE1crPmO3huUJwQj0vdewekVBq5XLOCCWImWfHku6yQijRzNO85kgvLAO64fGpvn5BbvFLh2YzJFjKMQeM1t4RGQACH8HZuJ8wO/UdOeu5Qhm/RpMJUCAvfozryHlObEQDwCoIoigROXJSwR/YheMZQ5WiycMsxDDlaI2gNiD0IjibluBwt3xx9gPTBm34UlahqoQ7mRp2gl2dw@L00utJF5rZnuIrpnIQqshx@DnTB6QBTkDXu/EIPVzlt62QBXiUOIViaO1/6QGKRWdvb21yqyWv8E5EWjSQR76RG16pBy6WGU43wpSqP3iZduBflFeLXMX/k/Td@mCrI5RS3naafsSYsBXIrx879/R1yC/hJ7wm/GV0LJuQ0t@CmGM7dXI5XIbWmm@Ne7iDvUjmK7YITZw06g5rj8nlCxEYKw8iTJ09CkqjHywaXg0alago@40TedDpNQQxRzIv5fHgX6Z16iKFDpKHhXdxGtpKk8aaAQY@e7969gwLnMJ@1IzCjmZM01EKFBoIH26fAtufR4k61UOXYOANRSgVCMrRo4cgSXMWYgTqa5dhSKFZPoiOTVitgDCMksF7MABhDU1JQuLDlovS1FVIsrzwCNclHHDZkY9M4Zx@v02T0ZSrFbBR49wm5@@TRo8PHx5NOh3Am/Wyv2Z14rmH6fgbDDh7fY/VQrZayqVYLuXJcU1HYcYc1Getj7ujes6PnNcK4FBZQhuajTqe7Q75UFS41mXy2m/JwfNwzefzylMs/x2ttyYqMWgVBnE01uZRhonUF9Q7/cNa5R/7wjjsjGTnP83mlhNZuFqdtgY6fd6cE90VkmyhA@8a1dOLuLuUA1zwXEpND6NEkz1SOOQSFOohWrUSOMnMo5RICPGEfbdO45vPDY0B9/IQoqixyzc/JTETShAXXtBu26QyD0TZ@9ZZvy3wi99stOY8/VdPgqhRKeaVY7mxt2ecCJtSm9eEcVwMu4PFcwAx/FQ7CfZUjXwUvOIQF4fCL1iQcbD96Ume1EV8xJRkg8Hng8UoRWm@WwwmDEB83SRyAGBrK6owbl9r6@tcD0mwePr4nHN3HUYPZiEQLCQWrL45EWif6U8@koUNC@tanFn5/TOxb/sTW59AKgSGpxWIxAExH94naVOkji9HH68KgPj1wL2Y6R0B0DrjU7Wh4hCvfrtUa75RCGSiq1d5pqsqBB7cD/b012ILqQxeH7EjsxzuNgiLnlGiWgWR5nq/7QIqmVaQdLqXwPNw0TeNoiyBczeQIXSD0Tm40hFD6FhS6PojDne/1WUONjxB2dmsJq8kMFkMggAwDj8hRWJmFhU@RwIas4IpZ@qHVeigi5Nu3NRwc0gpynHdCWUMWUIzbWkHDogE/8O2kCuVw4gry10lxthmQfgPcqTZmmLVOJcUTfELppVVkLtVKQVvlWp1W4//7X6fFdWb/eP/Allarwc1A5CXP0Bth6J2s/Djukftk@X/yZJx8vPY/fuI@euKOXfhDB/YI5VF9@a/XVx6v/4eiEEVOHXooLjBnUJ3gV5CL3D/6A5o7rdJsynQ33GSxSdcvt5RqoXMITaZFOrvR/otNgN5lr44Q3PiiwWOGpcAKXydp@qY9EHFVcIPfnTQ1WeV3w52em1HEZr/Rdw36met6X7Twc@P4ogqLUCjwddfBPdMa0bwk9EDZc27YOKMv03JmYyjiNhyeo9tcX@y5/bnoB3NQFAzXdr1GGgyidBSwxG6CpoyDwnuaVqhBlsSJO9nj1GI511JkUDrwVCp5Nb9l7pXLtb5o2Kbu7RVrxUoeHuJZ472iXBuKnz96@CAIJs@g4zT9YK9QhQi4cRVuMbNXqRWLUGN5PteiyXTwI72sKxK2tkB4m3pfgDtOKvuCWulA5L7lNRrp9J6mqIJS0@TKglsyDng@UpoFubArwR2sNwknq6GbBJ4ik5VdaYLFB04A0cHZA2dxV@qB0wJndVeywDltaoq8K01ZKSLPmhwSk0Ne5bEk8yPlPOw/ao7rmAuultfz1jllbW0wGCx2znPLB04/F9gTMH0h6PneefxYFxJwNTLNC9YyEHz0AZTheTgHX@PVYoWvt@rL53KJr3cW3P7Y7Fs6frq5LZ9fjVWCXp1hTUFCbcItap7rBrWeOXA9cwmoKaUIkBF0FaDAL@Lk2jKmeH41uVICaHZ@FUuhyC/iWBFZ3GIBhcn4Da3t5UsutfPsU63ZhIpxXiirhWKhqGqlUrGsgiZSLZSKFShUuSQXVRVaYaFaqZYX0Aok6V2Kfp6M3D2PWkeNbtCe0Wtsh8FWh2TfPbbs84omsHacydahG0u941K3nn2qNpubBzQyoLl9qgrNhlasgktDl6rRTk9VBVUTNEVQNPzf4FDx/@HwKvxVvEIsTeWOcd@Rx6BQgb7okIe4f0HgkmPXpa943DGNDRB3Rzrd4@Su5/r@3wHmju6csKB7FtvsMw56oONnvPyxFYw2QLyYjHHLEtP7B8NwOO4BgSg9GcAduHi2664DKJMXTzfk8lG8vTYwg@2vDeDPjj56cJy4Hx8e3H3AlcidJ4/vXboVQ6AieXh4/zh@LLPQKGoxRvHzhw8fXn4Mb4UnL54Npq6HJ3f/yYvC8hJ74ZsxXAGOVaDYmyIJL/hIrRNQIckWGGeRQ@HwpZzbhSq5HTqLpaVTRudn7LUfy4/f22FvjtW44@hdIJ2@PNkzicF2psHhJ7prXGg/KuUqx02I456Rskz6rm3r@E3ywRZ4jnSf9EwTrSLbxpqISZ@5nt0/s/rmFug0kEZVwe8/IxHcA0Aynhr0pWfQXnEP0j5@LRxndXv21CTTCdnoCTf0QqdnDUfQZZ@5EQDX03UC55c9IL6ZPILrPQKWBvW7EmJfBedSXDXF83d5/oEe6HXPLL986kG37Q/N5uEMqio0HN2b5yt5jQ@K/H1Sc17uDHFm0HYnaL/6k9bOFNTyrS0wwv/qN3/0t3/8K3tqW74r45jmo4cFdQ6qhSLVe413RCmNexfNvYK7jyo82oE7XTNVGeLX5mt@saTsYffqNeTcfurofi20jwjaP4RaM6EZJFJzWq1WipWqplbylWqlUFRKxWJeUfNKuVKuAmpZqSilSrGq5CuFKug5hSqEFsGuZUaUFBlI0k4N0DoGfsJ4l1rk4ghMbzbzT95m9CxJ6fHzlPAmxOE5HC0J6GtlO1YDelOiyEQrE8CoE4Ok7t@/K9@/z/N38AEXPt2Veb6PD8WKLJfv8LxJQ@5WUGfjXRangpvB8QF7kOU7UCxThgD3Uef5ET4clnAom@ctfLh7cP8@pjPABxXjA9gJC2EPdvRQBjAHH8CKowjexNgA7IClU6CEHuIDJokh91nIXQjj@Y8icjDkGQNjCB5EOT044Pkj9nBwgCF3abaLjNBP8OGAHjzvwQO0Fp4fgmPoQTvl@R44sc3wvAEuY66DH34uGrfadgKd5@eMPcggnp9RaN044flu5I/JfBpSU0Tu1uiDwnK9Tx@q@ON5NSIawbT4QeP5QvxQgLw9ePCpPgr65pAdc4/dDcjpgweabs2mh/d7H33UGw573vzg8KNnGHT37gNQTeZTrzfshRF7XThciHX3gaqfjOeXD8j1Ubdb0@21QZ90uwXduRTUnXdNpBBivQHKwmOICY27dyHo7oPuvr5uBQdF2EVxMYZ7D487Y7jf0XssKDpoEL3Pej2@jtVfktoZDi0SXIyBzfEExK@TH@uG59bxedYgch61nHmrJHfqNICMwbKQ6wsMH2TwquOIZPZ83po15E5j1iiHSyYHGb49U4sWn98a7ynVYm1L31PUQm5Wwzdi3UGapAVlj2SU2ztvSeZxdk8FK2OLb@/tCXxL6eyVyi9RKtXwsqcqlVpBVkmWPWrlGsSR0zIheMm2yp29crG2jFwu53RJrZXLoMkBfwLQB3o4LNglmcyZqZ9ks0g6HXqC/NCMkznNtFUfZGb5WYMRSebZ@qyh1Nl@s0S@hC2T6ePm5lMD97QkDOkQEM725Bqu/snwSrXCAw2SlMmCEFosFow55wUwV87P/fPz9iIWjRK4luN7n33t@OT4@HOqSzbD4bKn7DPt9fDxowd3xaMn0RPuVy7eRx3X9cS7KNtWQpiyG3kdg@UiPoDeGezKyA/iBJ5ri4d0PSwoylFAtGWKGO4dKh4/WMHzfOSesZQhkl@nG9DhO8i4nbvVJ3qjCS69TzKUKqJnz6he0G02G93G2BxPgjlkMYr1CaF7nS/RHPmMdvo5CtzUi0Y/H3juOAzoNuQFdE@z1AzwdBtEUF6N3f4rNWfU@7iL@53GHYxc78K9Vzcbpue5Hg9GIV8f7DmNqePrA/Op6eHr1EdPtkFLwd0IMgNiZrdJ@xCh76JxsxCaHnGWlD2ejjO60OxlV71w1Dj2QOZkvhZl@hwHVoFenl/UBw2SeQmgb@DZ2yaZvngnu1eoA5/ukG4WvORXg1cDopJSoU5tmAziggZH@YP51rON5iegXDHUJ6RWA2rCgj4BrJgYIIYyoCF6dmIt6kbDJhmBzLKUR4X6sNHC6Bd42RVADxCE1kWHawrCZ1wTGnV9ntIb/rRHv/9B5J6iyqX6DPyUcqE@gtLVX87qXmMy9cy6DY/hCDKhOdXrwFNgHaB5e5F5/wvfyO4KxQbzq1NUF6hIdMVuY1Z3cEdBqBcNrQEBuVZBzhcroGMUy3lQDNRSXinltXwhL5TRF7SCfDEPnmA7ge6SsTM8IXxensmikldMJZ@RX1n9V9n8SUaG/FOmZfOBe@hMxwR9oKiwbtJnuOvZnLoDrOm7RN8VaFUFUVLHfAHPR2Ri5UcU0zNTt1mErEC0nYy9nUGg7ePp5LDVqdUOZ5OvQVBGeLNXypXl3Ntstp7ZyjZ88w3XrHNNFDs015MtqLjh4Drxp@MWFDK4lLJaa7V6mMWynNdkDXJndS@Gu3yT7@TlrZICRbSgo1AKYWIjObaMatHSb9JFnd42oeiUqlrnRDqkq1VUoSoVd4oyG1dmMblJKPaQkyTT5sOF8ulMOl1W0@ml3ZtN13FqbYtfTpFQa5iuecykQQyT9G21WNrjQYnja3xV5QFsKUWROCJHBIMat@BQDyUFsKLPucX5YhfM/q9wz/Ed7l31Jf7KLx8dPMHf/f0Urvsm@1@BsCr4V14@evHkxZP79D3d5at1X@bY54hE13iL3VSdsB/O1e7vky977HOpGr7NugX4SE4UxCZ9yXmfpdIOt9uQtgj5sovQc7vNl@zexreXADVHdzFukQ5dHGpaaK@ST3VQvfZIGhiqe@OWqmqdllqGDhyEfUtmoKqq1IGKboq@adeEyjI7B6J3c018lfkTMp/rOSHK0e1ac5jbltV56rTLl6oaexO3qcgnZCt9ewe/eSyQ1OnJVlPdyaWf1rRc@l5aK6ROM@3tZk6ZpyWyk1PnA1zVgqsjpDTAqebOLW0n/SJXqwzzNSWHVxWutTQRtlL73fx@tupztH6Q1AqDt6oHjYPhs4NwEJkc3G1W1Hn4CnbqZZevlEMS29vAMjX3crUQm6A1vMQJpEvlRn6GYx/XwKbr6dR5mqTSi/Sile5wqX36srjKXhYnqfh1cVybEk6raoUSyaZINnwqV1N@Jp7T/Ep6P5XGqcOa779L0VYSvYH7ySsV2mzKcSMPMIZxFBI0jWIRJ81S0quJ/3W1oj06euLc8@6bXKq9dbHl4mxnNO4Oxzvn468RMoFiSpN2IzVrFMIpKKXZFJRdFXfWKZMa9JoDpSTIF00mGJo0oKRCyPtf@PXCbLcCz6qswLOqFnNqs6nsgJaWmrz/4vcCb07ODz89eEjSOKH1t3/8Q7X8t3/8b@hS2vSCTnKpWjkFkOhUSuXU@fnk/Bx0pAULK6Y6qSsriDrAH0nRq@UdEXIjVXRwdKUU4yNok2Ulm/KFVLiAulQUMhlFUrM7WkXOQshFuHtJRpUr8BhNHVMvvlTks6nDZ1ZRVfZ39yBne1pBrW9BWSrxi/8k/u2afhUKp/Lo1QUh8GA0@8OhpVKXJJHaO2H3HRF2yTuctX0nbJFXjSaugFJwu4BoonIHX0PGef90MyftpAlYoaTZWtQXnRyd66Qm/ssdp32JD@0tfLVt1WvHgZ@549OfadJH6uHDY/Rk7rz2@cxOVpL6fSq9cSZZEJop1sq6Jik2oarsSEDlTjRNyX6C0M6@/4VfU9XS3/7xL190L7qfq2DBV6slRU399Ke7U2fqm/3mTyHi02iLKKg/htXHenrsnpiOL8ZWOO0ywGa30BFb74Tt0WWFsWKHaPBcauqgpcLgI1serXcC@ps1dMw@teW5U9Q5aYl22aZM/QwF2yGgqueppUN3gcnWOS6yApgl4w2NPMVBdnBL0VYny51zX8Ug0GkIWEN17qtLVATHPGzbNbq@PfUm9JXADI2ndPLkNkSBFL6KG15tAXSWhL2fAJJX2rkalZHsU65R/ZSMTd/H7bOgL@e@ClHCfZftOZnonm9SSMuBHldEEEonDei3IO0OpG2zCF3qm6G5ZwB5wqhjkRwwcLivgk5GuWCBqkasXQCogzj5KjAA8pAJEVsdsku0LDm3crn6cm@uBYFCx1fk9GjzKA6jIbY@sCmOXEc48ALDCr/0ifUiLGFQlBOeERKGg63taYBphtHpEyq/FlSH2QejAlxnIywhmjVy@/aSqkbD6mcJzRHiP7EmODBJy8FZTysgi2zcW/0anye461k98o2rHXA8R8mFWiew7c7qiaiEx8cFx8H/gyst1shLRUUD6piBsLxYqzCAZRAZ2c7K0CC7DaKo5SyJiTeAdoMSRbcWiQ339uyWqH4eBS6Awp@mou/ogLA6Tg72hvX2nmlfjC9ihvsEDJYpfsQEOKkzYRB@P5zt3IdC7yiIYsexICuWTaEHlgfGIl15FO25ldGULEZb7lFG6aBvB6kFgu/oFLN4o7EQmsBdxz2gwnS26J5RhgsF6k9ch24aFaBowrekoEaAjIIEHruBycieOmf40auwbGjkJEWQS7AOsOYjxXQTLPq1cBoXV/L0PFM/iXiTJ@ZQJMa4T9QqydCK5uDktxOjy9JIlOAeWB3I455tjoGk56ZJX8z1a5I0BEVv2sMZVumRBfVqdN@CnsfxpfDD7NKZdWJJx7j7rOAO8P1dihywgG6IzY8tBQIDbWr3ie26J8S2Tkw2hp9JbsCF@@2X8mA55IGzyxMYW8O1aqqWxyEiJc@g4CzDrcyclXwi7lZmnr1615StTBdL9IL2YJaHH10/1Z0Ef@lxwYXDDf7c5@h@Yw2Cy4gy8CzGIhdaJtu6J41796SzIvC@D1oVLV8fomBMEeeGJhk@xWdFf2JbAXVyE888JThwwGEfA0LT6IYkYCuG3H6VdgC07UHLwj3AAq8GJZcDSrx@xoCmFwp4h9wimsohIKSMoIwAwIFF31jFDmEQFfPhB30oGJFOiKBcgdY57kMY7jEUVj@MH9VudNMd2ZbVm2yF6LDToWk1CGsW0UMx8YCtA@szzfoWBJaAwjWUbGX4HKDN8VmeoY7jX47OajtHZUmNXMWUJ4ghZDVgoaqCjiKH7mi5/DoVBwF3dJ99wgBrfY2@LCvS7e6mniWaPn6xyXcd3ZYmQws0YVcKzPEk/Dauhd9ED/EuXQL7UJs4GU32ZqjPNqq35@zOcQO/Ea7py6QHfho7x1P8INFwfIr2FBA88GmFum/Rj5kZmXCJIat/aid/HtW/GtY/oZJeIBJCEM0sP88beUCW7xkn@cFZvx4GnNIGCcihFM3IEzeh9KKHsR@5rMkghnADlKNxUM8@oXPngIlnY@nLpFkOI8h59Bg@Tyxc0@uYZ@TA8/R5hoZnERorcGZO1R4yh26fhoATt3c@ZzsiWrPWvLMSfRZHh04tXo4CgjyDPde1SNn2mBg@Y@EzCJ@x8Nky0SjZ1qzDVDL0WmB2sNbj4uQIEtHMI5gF20pyGUIxgx5OFIYCIecrfgs4jQaNHfGbPUE5NqKKAXViAgw3M1LrZbvV7ji@ebbTyUlDqOw8ZQSUOKBudShPz/qxG7lvn9oT11/xgu6Dqjch3ehljMLawOoK5jEuIFoxGL8s3P5vOA7XzTCFIMwwYEA9DAJRNTgIMla2Hu/HSgOh4rT4JY8ZYa2QmA7VvsKg0A/UJcZ6xtgkok4CEfrHWQIyIYRELYd9ny@SDp95LsBEsAL9pBiIyDlJd9LAyUtNhcmaOi2kBFWCEJEJbEd1tXE5K1E4FEXrUlAim4uw/JPkb31p8gfQLtZTTyss6zDqXLKp4AJmUCHC5kK5SpqNRLkCBdKObpse9FyHTD8Ne2tIZkeKzAyWDmbBP7MCY5RJFL6RZeVD3xLnHb4WV4V5owFZnDdYs2TtImIpY3gczQ@jzaOKEMZnAgRwyGujmWG0WTLarNFggoPMNkQ7SxA5o0TOWBQGPdtAZCeMBtbTUdS9YPF0QDvFFdY84FNYNwpq0IQnvn5q4nKF19PxBK2qKM2lzKG1IKxDqGJjPTM6a1NvJYhOCK1LCLAiXkHQZ5/6rXGXBZ4ixE@xjGKsjGQUewqrAZMVUMGoCK5zzAaKKxm1gUHh53O0H4C2y@daHK/Q4XX8yezk85FndCpXPeVVSGXVU85f@v2DeHaQs4kGmtA@FLmAAhktmRcO27hlRedIkYMpGDig1fXOXJJZo2yDvzQNo0o92@1JYx2XHeEHQJmvOJlnI/sB56fI/sQN9MAtFGrMaLJotVuXPrMZrKHj4neDEpvdgq7Xd03fSQdQqIY7dCzfzINhEqrsJl2wwrbt5pJ6cuh0fY4LV8AxMxZRs3qFqm63i58k73YzuAw1W4vftKCrUrF6ptMc2r/gSsQH8RQifTLJuL3XphFkb8aJOz6H0Y4t4yTzZBIG4q42BwRkmAH6P4SOQIMhvru0HOnm@6hK96AWIxNH7tgdgtY39UUcgeUuoT9a4kaC9MmE0pInOpq0tcS@37SVZIy8ng2jfvKlo5JP1IyejeOrqwhWmJEn3mUeI2e9Ncl1NybHokXpPf/y9D5P0vv8enqpFX6ZZmaaN1jgl0tayywxAOCSDO1mMjDrILf6V8hZISX2Rr2KRfhgEvt0WV8fKT0A0IMQXBxA/cjHTz48xYR/uon/1xdgFP3wQ4tPh2ZPns9B3oxxiTnbkcqPppkzAH6URdlzNbm4at/7wLQAFr@yeR9VCFBjqeBycA9xaJj4XQ4/3sw9QnxDnceVdFfqPV1e12CBa2jyTvPkRN1cRPe6fdPW52Y/E0LmE3ijHD8Dg43Kqw/LOAo6KvRcZutloO/KxqHQjSPTGVBtQ5XR/9/uvm67bVxZ89p6CkR2WmJMUZITO4kcOZFtOdHejp1jO8nOOI6bliibHf21KP@ok/Q651zMC8zczyPMq5x3OFfzFHvqqwJIUJIVp3vP7FmT1W2RBFAoFAqFAlBVcK8c53a2kixhzD28U84YNm6nH9KnRDO2@KqyW03rgFxuEduxVxz7HfeR0Mzv96KOBIfXclTmH@lJBLn5PkGIDjJ7lt2kWmee@DzIx026w4wQ5/XSTc597OUMRISfm@7DHyPR91tKnWsVqppezqRvGZjd4@G8Hre4wvCkHDfdjSW/x3R35jmL1QRYIsK2fmwKmYIM25hmM29DlC9ze6zfm5IJ@Mb7dL1bZpXTGQI1LsmSbhTycpv1CyeDlXGDfrHh9I5@AfA8GJ0KQ5m2YU9LX52pOKXrDyytRX8hJZ2gWFQUkms0rFwZ80zZv3yL62zeWmdzqs5mqs54BKSrtDJlmqkqdS@ge@Z1QSdoj26RzkjC2pl@5olt@tfr@0PsVnzJhblK6KrcVa5CAjkX5Cr1PAnlXCtX2eaHKFc55IfPucpf6SEZW7mvuYoZFsgwpFd@eIHvWoTjvZmrbOWdb5mR/zmITL1erhL3KeV5Lq9MESIF2k1aI47Yen3dzNEwoImNlUpXgWMiF8sn3odx@f8S/Sf3hmDBxInY43zAmdWyKqcmDWvGkHpo2vA6/esAivL0SK7o2by@v8O2ZXEWVLNMazy7DIMnNXwxlxZGghhS@USDfglByM3KbIyUNZPdER1dO3Eod3K6frkPi/WBVp7TjynzSVIJXxajy5v@SoOQDrwbnih8G55T6JjqGCOcyToz0AJRf87NaRT6Oo2L7n27h3ivO52JsC2YLNJLDNaS6aTD8eEc3yjWH6SZhFPhHBHaZXhTTgYluHeiGEsFPTJvSebPumUQDPbgd@Y1xyoH1FIiCInHpRMZZfG8wLIYSYmsszRVGXyEgiVzaIQHzc98Ec@2fuR8Im5cnitum4ZMWamSJVdaTFJhD0H7Lv2R1B4vXusI5fdjy1dT8gZ7LXkAsErGtYh87f@A/t4X/d0o1IYIExXMUqxnT6XT6vXcWXYC805S7XQHItFV285M5SiuISE5rQ4szXwer02p@DD5ECVfKo2hT2j7hmzxmuA7dJtcWwgsaAnDq/THzyv08fPK7YSa1kg6V55RWjzUpOFIw2NMk6bNx1UaPquLkcL7237nhzt4mO5gu/MAjxswnCC5jPLhZY@tXJKxTWJbvkCklitKBDkfl8bdnHwkcc9Ht/GxLX3YPz3Y3t/b/UCT7uPHjx09R48T/DBqsdcaz@MCWe6yMvPBjGXLCi1fGzCR4e346KI/HN372MtOyRIR1qQMIHiNYT89xh0tyyx5PjF2qZzktSiqYX1OhoGfkkpQdXxM2aGm64gIEozyD3wNxKi3RG@XV2sOX8x1etrzu3BkwPRlrv3Vsxi6xpyIO39fvFe8jIZ82aFcMnWdyXCEGbW9r96/qh2po1d1tfN266/qw/5b9b62d4SgIG/ebu42thT9X987rKtMygTvXTBEwAxFdN0OmgHfwrhSKj1SDHmrPxiL3MlvOfL90O@qV/1mgGOqZ5HffXEhL14vGG1IqTouJ8MeZsgXd3XDEewtRn3iX1rGQrlpsUMnXC4U5T2jNW0Xa95uvxW2Q8qbwdp3EAaR8QFUnZB6kOSt8Zp3RUm68HG59zm2VLER24GK1sJRQAdnNwTGF/srkBg5uEDQ8pQmXPzvhyl4VD94fagQiWZrf2@7cdTY3ztUO/sH9PrmQ2PvJdGzcXh00Nh8iyTO@Hp/u7HT2KrxB0Gg5CmEiPnlMhrNRcFDdqZK8zNOvr0BdX/8lt71hgavrn12bY1U7rIH6RP6nfC3oJVbz1xGUF/gTstHBSq/VDt4@Y7mfBX8ihNOcxTM9gfZtxFfdLZUUs@4NhosGzTe1vVwpWmvUHb4PKI7VrhcLljneDB5fnaVAc5GPK0wUNkt2Khg71vCxvBYNqCponsEG6CMwUpV/dIPe/lczn3GIDeotmanj2jIUpsYEeoXFH1hTE3WM0wxbSsDoPAdafSwH1Rejz8Q39OHFV3taCgZ1MP4g2RQj@QDVNEGbEfUqs5xOdq/hHhWa/Lhl@5gh4@F1eP4w6bPq9gnGifpN@5SX50ld4B2B50A7C27PHxbnoRPQpGI84cwEOnIwAjUWUAsTzJRjhLZto1yZknYtHHUoM3e5L5OpBI3wE7Ib48ila86njqCcVDQ42OMljrv@D0xgUpMd5j31BOEWatqz/mw1xwynoq9cQZ9ZkB1NlZpPOJy21orDO5ajkpuTtXoaxtJvvjPmKB9D4HNKQT@CBgCVEitdJo8U7G3McD025qV81GfOBL7tr/b@YmdW5fNIFVAW23lfwl/@83RRHZT6yRjp8jYURf9FgxJreSjzHZ/SGOcxSpftQop2LzoD0ah9GE@3QI@ceJpjnJjYqPafq5upGoDHSZr7PV7VqVnxMW31HpGTHmXWpnj5ew8Fl/JxZPE@TQJi90d0PHP@leBdXbm4hDpOsD2CynCfFZuX4XJ@mcmkR2/q6h4/OlJdWN782Ph95/dk2LxXMSC3CBpjA7xv1ytiZmEz/nYYHEIvUuPNA00E12eobS2wdPSEqPcAKN14EVI67oXp@txmpgbT3@Hp9Lkd/749WtVShUgmfR1pdFFPpFurjo2Vbpc5kRpExBLdhKyJOvz5ovLMGN5/QLuSeiFdaJID3IE6/bUhZ00IESEmNadXbZJssixs@nuGL6jNtiiIrnUFk5Edn8UP@U3q8sbTjExKFEWOfNGRLsGctlxLLMUnq@mwG3PB0fy@@7gnszFTqaHH4K2PRfaD@FWWL4dlkxLFqy7g/19DliZ3P4QWGq7eztgmSSnocWcHjOnu7QYW9POr/Hnqb7jsUdgMPdiByUGatV22eMjanOvQF4KODaYRCE6PNquHxyorKxPqCzJPSwZWloMAvY99Saxtg17LOy8WGmKF8ux8mS@pCzazL95g3km8W4RFVoHcTU9YmGRXN/cDm9E6umZhVUItr5ngWgol8bui5FB0bEG/I3WgIRs0mlWAzMzm7kok08Y2Ubgmm6u6Ma2DT9bWMvcTVlpVWkDsm2C/HN4lszuv/eiH1dMPaJgIZQVGtwiTZrmG1onHFLFA8roeekenNMtpkthZC8K9qKhHQy/SmkN@88zFDOSKOGiC1tiXSvHGjXRj5eMmsMGiZgGfFh66kSxaKYEI@L5yzO7Q51k0sunpyBSMh0q/cLmCip@8m09vr89n8yT1Vght8faEmNzbLA8we6shr1@e6b7sIVemxQPk1WRtJ1bVeEfU5XMEqmaDM1nNsYkEuS11dWH34M92QpTvPBnYcscMik/R90Bre8TkNE44u194tzGnmvSEwaYQzoxrTcDZqIgqToz5pRU23kysvEjXGRfiJDBrRzNC4I7UaujbiZwmw1dZiQbOmeZaoM1hOOGyqiZov63@dVBIH@3vns/Xp8MNmSC6eA3WOW/7g@jIPHKs4LqWJ8QZiD9LRgOe5xN/Jm6gJJnN6a5znbsbScGr9IqJPJ5m92StvZOErNb1@w1cCW8vehdX/gj7O6tT27vFcrrdlN3Grt19YDDzrZTe5HZYdaxZM@9sDcPAZbBvC@B6YN9@O5HFfqfcHANSCITe/PlmTbOd3FjipDWfMyXrWmzUC1by5O9346afg9hWNzs/Uhl3Z@oIO/C1vd3nFk766X1VHlCLhr08lTKzRa8LBelb9jQBaQ0COlNfLcmLHhqGEtJuNec92EfhYOt4EZ2z9hy0i@Wn5TWnma4dT135HaPn564D5rVrKLJ1@91o8vhdevzef/iqq06avDL2U1z/NuvSq0@Qkh7tfKThCwvr1WLHJn5sUK0@6cl5lyN4HMOv46r6T3j0J1TyTp8/Z5y@IEXzRV4SExwqXrQNVwIF7tRtXu8dlLtVUvr3ePeyTqc/EbL1dFyeTmPDz/RLEoyRk7mj0cnmFPtXdegd6UQN5dvhNauIYpdQ@jLa38Y9ndrey9Tu3FQALAFpm29eUOdzZMzC7Bmg@@J1wuu83qbzFXg2AwUpMwCewWV4TLP@8nYjmmFhBn1ikvabHTDf8dOZqHkXQ5GfU4xQTbBWupr@DWzYNyYSryjQFmOQxOKE/4FBCfJk8fBkHwdixV1oSzqWhm@k44F4hglWRxmP2az8CkEotqX6/gkE3mB37wAEh1Sq79yMfgm441YLfJ4Fw@mHP6QHSZKJ3jEAQj9DPi0AVWw5h6x20eGmo/3Mh7kC@9RjdhPhg3kM6wpIgXm3@oL@zdx@WdEACH8guhcnt7i1JoXKZLiO8ibCwhJl17445gBbpXSKQtoLGBLfdUEOFuKM41QrSYTfV@4BjmFVvRPt6BQ5repZsT5HcnOJOFzav0WgZbcpZy0gZ9OUixvFSuYYiazRYqF71IDO120PHod0LAaq62g0yGkhRYLCTnwyP69uv7luP7oGHWexMhLemEqvZBK9yRdkEpyeTTBJ5kqdqbs4pck3zeVTbK5U3VVFSsvHvV00yOVJMm7Pi9v5I36p2GSeSPuSuHKOOFZKqFgpXya0fuSci9VJmbwOP1Y0jV/r@iej7FM5X2Rrh@/Gd1BARvPaluTCS71emHnuUxacQrYLEvUVEqK8y21ygyqqvbB1OKENDjs8/Ow3agmUJbLRuLwmMluPHuR9bSS8Tw/iYZ4MU4NrBljxKIS17nMhLthh0Wqh5PvWSAYJhhNmZG7YQqPdeGxBRa57plqxQtyaoBT0yaHeBV@kV/xxwz2NHIm3@LsxAXB/EYaL97NaQKx0L2XnU2mtDSBu4h81I2aM4skdY8nIc4WEnvWLnBcZyA@2G1sg9@L5YQtKIykmKJ7nKIpnWQoG/a9rQuR@C3z9@KDzEufdOxBJ7hRNSwzfPbCyqQc3EdBNIoQY4vD60SXg0EHp46s8F2zC7W@KmNlFcctCURrZvcyDVj2SH4XT9ohnQp5ah@Qr2EgkiREl@fncCaDB2z/GqIVOy7hyMvUemPZ0KAx83BF3MwDheAbLIA74bmNhPScjB5QOhr4zcDLkI4WkfaTkaa2Q325M@@nw28EkdxoSqtkMv9yGTY/b73Eee7jculh2SLZlT4OLnkPHyUOVkQkk7CCkI2r5UeZjHU23JSz4QIAumoXE/074s3gKuj1gkyNZgzOGJHSGgXDq6DlZTIHQXwIDLhgZZxMwg@7fzlsyuYOKV0@MSO8hCNXjsOIw/CL@VmOi5t8VuZmcGiVnDZTV1@FLRDQeJy0@zgd5gMLhAkQeqBQNxgRUR44Ko0Snz1rXFh36WIjiqiBOCfW2URMhl5/FDapZ3gnK9MhUHIMklTWa01gQvU1Oz6cg71ZCMA9JqGAQcAcJc3DIaMPzX8IB6UbZs7YfdMzRZJ@fR4rNNyDYUjSNyEw9woXs3CnDj561ThUh/s7R@9rB3VFz28O9t81tuvbavMDn3HjoJzjJatX@7skXeLTdDk136cP2dohlcxyQqa290HV//bmoH54qPYPVOP1m90GQSPwB7W9o0b90FWNva3dt9t8@k4Q1N7@kdptvG4cUbajfZdrNcUySTm1v6Ne1w@2XtFrbbOx2zj6wDXuNI72UBlO9WvqTe3gqLH1drd2oN68PXizf1hXaFhmu3G4tVtrvK5ve1Q/1anq7@p7R@rwVW13d6Kh@@/36geKjQSsVm7WCcvaJi1hURO3c7txUN86QoOSpy0iHiG466rDN/WtBh7qf6tTc2oHH1wN9LD@L28pEyWq7drr2ktqXCb/HapQv2y9PagjbBIocfh28/CocfT2qK5e7u9vM60P6wfvGlv1w3WV2d0/ZIK9Pay7VMdRjasmGEQtSqfnzbeHDaZbY@@I5oy3b2Dv4FAnvyfCEJY1KrrNBIYZBFpLRNo/@ACooAN3gKvev6rT9wPQlKlVAxVgUbF1ZGejComIR3Yz1V795W7jZX1vq47kfYB53zisO9RhjUNkaMAg4wOxDlX6lluNfiK85JGYNWM41@XuVI0dVdt@1wDmOjdxwGFDcwuTbeuVprmH4MjWJkrYx56B37U3VtrTn64CBPqc3pGZvUcTR0za2t@u04ysg1xlk4S3NOs8mQilZKfRTBMn0msqZE0rOLs8Pw177T58TONisvHRjc5d3E/m4EKlj5k50dT0/goXWFw8PX1XO6WF7uHpqePepWQKje@V0Nvg83I5uo24WgMrb2z8VCpC92cpQm38pA862VAPBxDIKdT/SUzf/G7gqGKxFehicN4HYLN1FMmxyQWOUkg0srMjboJKquSdCX4PNTtwwbwB7zVPsU8Ky0jO1I/oT@9r8iKTg/WBpLNsdxWLWMQyGuFvgalGKuGQCPxHRyQI21ylFwXB5/N8ya4Oa37vvN9vIdqtLsN5R7QOPM873yl@FpxPFC9Mlmdk@dhZXyARmXU3qzDx@bMmmdL94g25ZXn8OR3xj2OwkZgP2DXlqnizWm9a5n@S4rBIcpUObQH3Cu5k6Hyva39rvMdqrrTyaH3i@6v4u4wt2AsiVjBNeMdc7oR/Xp1IBhpgHIuDSBLqCBnFolXG2JvEma8p4wUyXYctWP7QXH0R8LxOJCFF9tLv2HViNh6GNzb2JIdfHtReb77d2SHRCWwfPVl9vLaeicNu/c2V3w@oh6P2ctSxAc3jpKdxkjVKtkjx4ZFihVZP2J8ZuFhERsTZN53GHxHnIbbbSFsyQZChuRGuRevBRC8bgA5ZxQE47mUMv84cmZoB8qmmOmhN179hFd8nXYl5QBuzdMbcazf4A9jx8DdDPG6QZiDNYhzHmDiXVhcs97I7xlSUFzccuAdZvKzhYwnjFtOAt7rYfhbetfymedvqxUhMGTFeudu5JCFxbxILZewqejKy33CcEb0BzNHD6MvfNL/R4wcd4I7D3fnRqDY6JDLuxCWxT51sRutGH2vIJ7j3BEHVTE3PFHb5HY0Ujz29nRwHBrFGA6OCO39g45sGvB7HEZmski1gX@Qc9UU4FcE7AGddc6x@J86d1RwNZd3ED9HvJiqFElhxkBOh2nVcR8Zk@RDHsTDkTJHpT9GD4f8TaTID/jNacRL0hFpWEMA7UZKhCq1o@cpECa/NQYN1upFQ0/70IQHzze6Yi7hh@vTmRvxriAS6d8bmwwcOe9jOzyAAmBwbG/b4jU3SLnxaOr3IOro4zkl6ze4gr/RcYaaKKbiFtROX1S7XnK3gxVGO7DVZFe5SUfVCFm5nPOppyTSxlFf3o6yAc0z8j@ID3gCJBzxz6YVYrU5yVkmPMiMHdKgla8JpxRGTSC39duup3QNlhchMyX598mUIRaA3gM90O/kCmL4S89x0xEWeidURR8FDbHYskzH56JB1Z2yI2QkA536LN0NwR8zoGhNER6BzqL4EmsrfZ0MRVJJYHSZxBiFuHY9Iy9PqdYw970yCQ2Ps3/bkvoBAdrVMDk8CfGgMbXd5T732x4Ry527NFhYrPjjsu7BdRGWyLaHL4z6cZr8/JNXRR7sJRzccO556rzcdgl50OdTxC2k@C4d6R8Io/VQN1CZZvfM0I/H4GbUoHMFboeUxf3CTugEsRCU8yU1hTeWJeQ2PbphNx/Bmuazyz5KUZ0QTDkvKRHym1nBdMOcSguqQoQFTMIzixQXbbHI9OHeIh991f/gZcz9UoF4raMWRSS2QvBcondTocYzH5kiaPuhHvKNBXYEdkJgSZdlIiw1VaY5@rNlJ2zVlk@iYiF3KLfnxemImNdZSVFHCuLp2Yr61AnUmqLSiQ4PGwULLK6uMyqwF17dbF2McLTR9bK2yH3uxSKmIElG9b1RHPIncjJ8@4Elv8lfvRxg99AVn3FoFBcLQWXGuOi3nGD/YFLwPg2HL3hMlTablD7D9xkuffo950Wwd6rB/TX8UBWNaATSL4U2RYZzm/9K/6J1u9Tv@edgPfVqnIZr@jUg8PI75ER12PuxfR3zVk9w5amVqjZNniS8jYdjwHp9LrluhuaJRMMjbZgqj4bh2IWEieOccRoDJXcXM34PJGGlxmUerSaFM2v@U7fHKzvqtZR@WZxWWE30A0AJuY8KCQnxIR@yYZDmfrk9lOJuXwcLxTBWU79xisZfC@CmRiI9hUhgbZKbMEuxGYGV2K8bHrRu3xTEIhwi0FGwHuIMoyvNn18dV9CRFnsNSoKLKT0pWUTlFuUEcQjyMbyf3yuN/MvaEwJ9Av/xwFrfMYgQWcW0TbSmS9YqOMkq4sHlgyDKaJTFJsfA87Fnuh3yXx80k1HTy@DZqsOUPKUU6zN4UV2JE5mnhgxsJ86ckck7HDiaVnMo5HLcDKkhtlC/dzrDB9@xnefDjEFd2ziCYtjTkvIX0baRqEpVwbfaEea2NssRU/v6IWVm5a69NELA6y@TMuhk@nzWaC3ughDK/4lirPyRhnJ2gnjb1yEWj/iB3R@rdKjtmRmabReum43zXEFiYrUqT5YMWk7Y6xuN4PTOJzwTTpCnGlmbEQ1i@8nPM5pNEvKmeYrxVT8ffocNtNEvspuJJJe7vlox9TIpXsOg1E008pBh3BCldj78fn1LDT2@XIBqmLK9OWWKcQmScjuXRAjVBpphKd6cQc5/GfYIeLaIc6m0R7ez@uZWok0ZyJuSpSUoFuQQ9EbgdTpsklwZtGF8gTJxouLGQihXOG3fMR3nlwhmCDCNBAEIrDgrJPpTs4CadNcFHfDtAO38Ka6EyJBE9bdgWDnHQ/5hgHJVfb@5oi4fTcaF8si6QbmJItKrgXPMgGX9zej0@vWEoU6SgIT6DFHGLpmTTxd1b9WfbQvkIgpTmZG3pW3LRGEctEzb0x046vYEOnFSlS6ZGVHognLJooLFAq5TzTiDLVWh/4VA4HtYNehjRAkI@5/GzrEsgnPdaKaY2ity0xsjiaHLLaHNUYUOKJAwl7yC/Hoqi6vLClQAEgjGVr5YJAsKaMvY4FODQOzbnpRDVfUQFq2UMS/rIUVETO88Z6SCqzvBo1cpRmpXjqQ2jMBMIKRaz8ySIkM4yO0sChSa6mbhYOR7Pbk@SgxRiw/tCceoK3StpGsY9JwTkO8RLTiJRjsvKLWkO5sRHq04qMeZvTn1aslJLk6lEnxjD40J5MvVJKZWaqnZlJV00VZLo4di1phKJFI6NcCwV/tw/dk2xQ57HNqHWIiOlZWj7bNzxTqtMWrd5v0TqGTtlGx3DwLM9w83y61SuWEkFZZ8fgF3l@MgAsdv/dGuNZarBRN8VwHHpjLNLXhaErLFmMdWjWVjpmkh7cYACs6btt9W7o52dVNjXs7ExNOoGw9VSqQQmPrOD3xvbamwlhf1iOnexfdnpFAfXfxm@Oyuy7A8CvhKgYlbQAXUJDYrI6w/P5WYI4EBZkbugHVmx1r9st@0rGHBCic6jbpOcOhqC4gkojI1e3h3xBhCD1BPsz2gg2vezikfftS@KpoZijqGoNEyCr7Lm9IzIgw9t2GfHJ1UMDILZWDPRvOVUN75gBsHNJtxZHL7Y@ZKYJ2dfBZ1O31XvcVk0IgUsfJsssLNjFyhJFpwwsnfvZcTxaF0VXIUdy68YWWxeBzgzMZl7JkxceMTGPwjO6zeDfPb4U5amFWryMpq5jPjUrsqeZx0dLP4OYIUPCe075e76g3yT6TSZmaZ6PYKTJ8LoYdmdufZJZXF4T0zT7Pu5QdTZ6HocrIGa7rAuYGLZc/dyS27JHhM3@/Gm3AYNSwJD44SYK3crAVezf55YvBq123eTinwNgHTsD0lEuQnlzwlEPgPgEaiHH9ETUbT/WqBhvTMRUEQUHFzWMS13UOAUBTKZ@83qr9f5Wq2mlgbLy6pW26SHQkHVNmtqGx82N9U2vW/i/afqyurqusjcbecLfdw0H7@pTYLBO5zLzYvhNr1SWhV@Y7DWRhcvFatL7vrSafXZxnpUPK5twq2fnv7z3/7rf/77fyvW9Mv/wMsmvxx/ijN5nldcan5Z@unbOt6Pt09yS2fHS4OT3Pk6uOzvHDW83xgV/MR81BueZRZlFrC@sh2pWWdz9BldVJm7/Lr@8DNJl4pabEbFRf01kpujWMYuNgPrewA/yjNawptLByaX8hlc6tb1x9iOp95pBjDAo/mGKEm4wA5UysvZitm4RziYOEN8qrKoI/GwznoVwKcliaQAX1yasQphLwp62AG/Yp1XmpfJ@PQbjk41/xY/vY7ON/s36sHHvHpQUg9c9SCb5Z/y2lP66iwVQ3jnSjZaDmSzLqUkRwswM1RRyIoerx/4rp0JcmcyS3xlDyCZMBWcWbzg3Hj1x84ycuFadJ5ZwA2mSrZI@JAJRRa/LPW@Ubd8oRzfsilXG1YUTvUqhiuzTlTi/oUK5EdiCJDU3BWCVPpUJU762CMZT0XzRfd1hm8TYsAg68HLHR73@EBz0VJP2zyn1lK45ojN5@Ur5sZ1cYZmtJEi9ScI8IGKLCdL7EmYW8xlxMrbaiU3U7yw7fZp5hNbh3EwMrbpUuh3ZTGBWHPbhFvqab8WbcgtxysqG8bHK1ZV2Unbb5WxinQvO6NwoN0VuHYMqC9xbd9kJKFHGZDAkZj9lekRxhsFJlLURLfIZVlj1eqj6TISeto1nTrY8eTkyCJC8VOexvbXibHtFNlLxLCD8AAjFZvytf2wE@moK0Mm9rk/PMPtgH6bL1QbybkZ7@fh5tcJjPvtGGmPIbPJeTKeqSmLg6F/3vVdtbjXPxr64wZNW6T5jJqeQy1ECCYggcGnq57VPIOwtEh3CVMkbgpbDuHygs5YX48mfZuNfU7QpWYo6LArGAQpdmJKBl9TfTVBx4Srf6ATbJSnhHd8GqlFLEteWBppSFnbbYaH2dTQyZga7LETD5xsRlCNR6bhBV3oEhNtlw9@SZJ3ECNA153VXoDaFWHtKerH7HQe9PzU5DToZIyjf3FdybyI8cxXUYo1UkZDeVxObrwDVqRHfkpHgZC5yYQzyizk8wsfI32d26I9j3CQ79gWv@irML6Aji8wY88Q9bYXirCcmKGSOzA81WDLf4LQ7vjnhN/42h@DFT8u5p/fKzrHnz72Th7kP/a@fvzNYUy0SDazbEEt6sNsI7H0WKGZseimXo1VWmRCDX7spTN87CnxYbFIQIgU88efiidfi4TQx0XHeVD8uCgESXUZMCnOr68I8MUpNBfTWBQXMwvOA8d0fv552VE0t/Iv@lA@OPJLWJhFJW/T0zpn2CZQ7Kf766W4nETFJyulRyvlR7QSOg9uCsPgEvNtIbo8C25IlYiwnKWp5@NvKW5IEeLbTeSv08cbaqdcayK@J5F2UtIiVA9zricTsxWV8YQnKD9RmcOlwsXFifP4OHzEgt9VxHImL8eCEtNBi/vymD@jfhf1@BHk2qR3iHAkrAzERoS3UAuAbC5fuY1DHTNccuzn5KktxG5lINS9xUVrtuj1ewWtrDlebh1KNLxmOk9KT0qTY3RqiKZG6JJWpnL3VHnj@eP/@O/7vy6OFjdWiu@H9Dta/HVx7cmiPNIDvT00b1eLG4vPkG3t2@K4SGtgenz8H/@Tym/8heAgZfyM/mysGlhr48WNQpWLfF3cWKOH8soK1fu//vVfqQ1LsmLDXaxLp65ixNYNRbb8HvMupasGWinL0lwiVtgxCzDEwpDW5vQCw6iblScl3qZb1FYVV4GOfGXsUfQUz4ZZIzYVkp0MY09BmpEUqKKCgoA0JhRtZdluGLMNMG@Cpvr5vrcW0QrgZ23OEVcZm27cj2AytCTLIurAvNRI63l52Cg9z8bmHZWssSlZNyoklnZa1j55uE7s8KYfjMJm2krCDNdu078OzjzwoRe0LmlN1Ys6/V@GxStiyW555Umxjc39IttxFwcMqTAYe7@RIqgvA6KFIRudumpIPdDvIoSXy7cFkUK/E59JmfskScseBE3Zw0rfSUxZxMfPleNhNMdLVOk8/yUFHjdn6osgrbvSPvao5P5BRWWX44ySj9e8DrB5w8axOgRGQaxhByybvAy3AbuDpj1ebXjOTkhcClHXJYvnt1qnvk7LZxay5qo0N7NwEXQG1WxbwrsjdipOTDT9Rc28FUohxA5CocCCDrC6wcinJXo1y1@wHk9qQJgUfdYah4pLyNrWefWqvlXlW1fmVH0tVV9Tj0JLSOqJecaKxqbsbCJbqtiqHAanOFKbWTHVFplLm4ce/wCDSLql0YZbgm4Oe0AS1ZLmaKsyu9tcXgsTj1wH4rMnW4tyc3VmMXF@dE0O8aCG7oR6PamMBASi4FZgoUzvh@IBUTXXjIa9jMTzm0g28T00GG7DPkKJ2mHrJPioTEu9K9x9E47Yl1IRCXRcWdsGOyOzRww6DrEVX0GbxcZL1gFLtSu82OKMpjsqfA20CQmVzco@1XFTxdfLtvXttXJRBH3IlsorDx@trj1@8hS3nC3o1s4Gg0IeVgGDC59gsEadp0U2vler2VxWPuEK6ukqAX0WWBzAwazr2nFM2Odr5161XNLASlmGdc3XaEhxvV3JIBOIw8DDjEBrlPwwm88/rxyjYScfW85X@p/428QHZIYz4Wh9Ib3VD2@SyFSZrgQcqLJg5qA4@YeIoOLoFDtv0G8fINpEAFtXYXuqaBcRIEYXw/7l@YXNHZ4ObXVEA4YIznGpsYJ6GYySAGMWVtBF9YZDw/K@qBp4x9MtgFEupgTofAKchpmOW@lrS1OMjhxNQoisCY9VHCFapqM2OzN39vqqvrc9idiifQ0dw/Vsy1ZS7jiSGQLI4K5eq7lHRF0d7YJdSbVMclNRlVnAlZCvzO7wPnylm7iI2qKKkdWsN4zy88hSZl5MQpsmRakfgdcMmOXS90lp/FpNK0AQIwj1blIsxNz4PMcmWYKT3ckYp@DlbMWyEX0dRhEHmNOVZR1tUcqZ@FaBhcwtALFvU8pKQ0oV9Cg/1vniZeltXOYoXtHYGtBmyPFKNZiZk6@ZYKvbSAJg49ZxQwu0v7G35artOv3Zeb/tQlHerP0V7Y6veL4d37LGt1xRjR3TBXa0WLa5hc3Ur3BRImYp6YCxCYIQvm25FTFIogbUGzua9jKoj1Nj@yThCrCrr5VwszuqBwkCvfAeyIJevMehONhdh79VZPNqWtLEIVX0sJAtrvkD26LJQlJrDElIeQcQK5Mg4kAtCbcvJAwvFuiseft67WIYu7Ezm6dTLCsLKlLbd4pE9jTP3kqZeWyxotlipYJ@nMcXzLdzeeMsaPe1L1rMHN/hjXt/jDcKd2eOwv8XzFH/53DHQ80dDyuQPcIdcdhw9ujka9j7MzjmbMxz8GkrPA@xP9S2XtGIkmsBYIEHDOFDSonlEtp2izhR@dkJy5PzEYyEVlbhGPCHGv9IN/5RBTKXH7eD/1cbX/gHN35VN361grlmRs9r1c4Kt/6PaXGiEubTH2Z2L9Rdyeb80Zau6ZauVTCbzujm/@stLfwfaulj3dLHFURMkAMHCV8/n5tFE6kdbjUaibmFl9FBu/K4x342VzpYe7WqWVo8tDuX0UUV2rr6w/g/0fg/gTTiJ1xDh7OI2DY0XsvL8lSc5UWz5F0OBScraYm010RGt9qrJ6xkPaInKBHSvLE11AsVUshdSUxOm7xEf0ykbzz53BVnke36skwcnFsLaFkRlp1kiIvmqy/JXFmL55VtjoGsto4Odpf/i5Ch63/WXmiEPLr2Ouh0zExiL8GO4qhTujFWcwD7UK85UqyiycnIjrS3d8wuC7dLNQ5sMTEvzl4kyFEbzv9oLdWFvmHdyo0tI6KNp8ubVRVMc83yQr5Q2yXT7CbrFv8hLn2qufRpRR3ohcFtpPL1hp/mxWSdtrK6Om8OkFIefjAASy7lnzOq/jc)

IP starts at the last `$`, like in PATH.

The code:

```
  d e9a5 6
  @#@@@@ @
1@ ## # #################################################@2
 c@  b@@4                                                @3
0#  8@###@7
 ^ f!
```

IP comes from below and hits instructions in the specified order.

Answer (score 1):

## 413. [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Shakespeare) ([drsam94](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl)), 17945 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;p 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405



















































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000';d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlpstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let r,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?/<p>3r=0+@#posHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyckCa
 ; ;:
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({ffb6793e-1f15-47fa-9ac8-8463ee203555}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKpIisSTb1KkpFKpbul2PdQq1a3bl2SxQBAkUQIBFgBKZEms6O7Z7XWPPbOenraj3fb4tnvWs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuz9OOGYT/4B5cfGhmPD/Q96z8kEQFAipbpte8OxIAEkMk@ezDx58uQ5mYlEV/OGP/tZAg9y5FizgeX4xDc8n/Rc88xwRXJvRnY10yuoOY5DqD13MBkZtu9VuQRRCLE0ezDRBgbpm5ZvuFniGQbpGpZzDuEqIdsTe@IZvQY85QixjXNyaOtmDzAQ3zk1bPOt4UJYnpD7hnU5uvSJ7oxGmt3zyNg1bZ@GFgg50uChP9FPidb1fFfTfdOxIai4lESJQHT9lMLRyGPXYCjKhDx2XM8ArI5ueJ6DnhXw1FzTebT35OMr8IpMPtYgI2PLmF5JUlHIC9Nwe1djqOTTkwcPrvrmyFcFxyYPrmdJyZO9ie8c@lfxF8jewLA1oooVUb0aWAQC@oZVlsvy1aAS1KHhm/pSOhDwwHShRrWg5oiu2VBDWH9bxBiN/RkRWJ1rlhXVp0c0j0y8iWZROHsy6hpuCOj5muub9oCcm/6Q@EPTi@JRaG@s6YbQMyxzZPpGj1gmRHL6ARZAbffIqTE7d1yo5gCnY1sziGjoZt/EKGE@ACEeKX9oMDwjbQaVbPvAEEQjHmTDMkJsaS4B8PeN7mRAnIk/nvgE8tYzPa1rAdLujPSMvjax/CzpQhgQmfqfDw07YGBAJwKKE4fl6vWEZs1Y8LnW6xEZeBfycWoQE6hGs1UluRz4E8cFqgFUmKMAGeVlVkZjCnUGVdR3qqQgyxB@EPlgbjXLc4LMLGcNA21on7TOEO@R6wxcbQTU6BmUpp8eHhFPd1x4ghNhWRu6CY2u@WR7myQPntxPkkZULaLb5aIqqpMLqIJEGEjONGsCHBKvCQfqx41ic1hlyY1klSSBLKpM8nmSh6ZaJmoBiKTIFXBAm1dzCpxFopZJXoEWVCA5tZTMYlp9VxuYlsEwDRBTCZkfQFS4ynmSU8okV8wx6IFj9RmoThMtkVyZFEukVCAluFZIRYVUMYk8USoFOItwAsYKZAkQqTnIoKwyZIs2ADyLfLdP@trItGZBCjQJnRQUUgKskHcFsKtlwAL3XA7PHJxlxLZ8xHH7Q6D8UDsD9IJlnqJkMiLhhNUpwU3a2pKoRESRy5L3hpg8kBEIWCiTEiRfBIrkIQtAZbUMyRdkVhBvaFhWEG3oYTSa25IMJ@S8BLQoQ03IQFMZiVqCE55B9qkg5FSQaCoIKRUEi6qCO4dJAFwRwopQrcU8S2aoeaeQEEtH7dEKAIkOaBSkOAo0BYkEGKDWCJAaqjwPTJFDpijkCOQf8lIqEpBpZYWU86RcIkDPikygfhTIF3KMArJUgfwoiAz4QAFGUCBPClBbAaRKrkC4GLGVHIZD3BzEBdIoeYiTBzdUnFLEE@IBdyiQpAJpqmplwZCQN7UA5S3kKKeqRajdEoQB3VTIqwospUJu1TKEY9wy0LCMjAzsywihIR2gVpD1gReBGAXID8ULsOBWSwHzatZ4qHVRcrOY3T5GLWKTKCIZIaqMxYN7HqkJWZEBDbYGyL4KHJCjLQfu@Sh5SwEkTURv9EwqrC0T5JgSUaiUpQz5Whv7C7IpRZqj8cwfRn4q83NAiJogCI2Bps@iQGiF2Shw4VvMoa9K5e4CkZxHXw@krDPxrAWSyJFXaVLGmWkt/MrUr2dovb7pDd8t8pqniXQNzbfN00UqhUI2RlQtFlDEgCWvUi4O65sCdF2DIboWZVFLCDN2ogpayrKi0Ox1jf7EHhhCpRzLHw3xJ64PncwizQrzds3BAPrnBR4lS4tJO82Fd4Hm0MrlfC7yROpimq4JXfldog9BuYgCKwx/pbLAkVMRx0zrYg8vgBYGPUIF@7C@OSXduzrtQRYZzFE66UNzHAJX1wLHKpcmMi0XY7xBKfe2LEfiGY@2@Nox7VSSJNPcnIN@h2mW8V4bOrcX2GNhH4ysC32sQzWIhfhM2WEvmQaiLXf40ANbIEahUnQNe2Psmwzat4Z4TF8kkAiohIZzhmor7SCXkvFoJ9p1UUsFjadnuC5BWFBtvSztbr1J1zPeTFCnWuSrD/23Ad18XzOtKAO0H9F8qgzAPelBerPlbPddZ0Q7mxF2p5bjjNeoLtB5nyOih865scj6om/XxmMLNCjwN5gCB5k516i@TZXzeKosQxAJ40GFA0KaFGgepmvolPZB0SF2DnSU5SxWidq4m0Ms92KqVQ4aC6gdHsaxJ5ZVBZ3H0EmuIfWMMwl9mPq1rHZhHkKFDNSqAEVXA70Zc05zEWG6q4pU1TsJa9ZzRstFY/3rYVT0oYlKknWuzaD2@tC1GlNtBNo9QRUaWi4ZAcewGsSaAIMCi3VIeo6d9CMs5y4otFDoqCRUaUaa@ObIAOvHgShY43maaezdac66M2BlSq28SM0dlpMrhBK5q4RiHvmYB2ssoPr1JjpSDdM2bcpBoC55qO@7ICqZH@e7pNXS4HRBtxsHFp6IDgR8hlmLGQsea@2BFq5TjKivGrYHJoYnEhPtL@D8gdMHZjs3oewgsCDqArdOiYAkiLymoi5ylOTIQKNTi5hEH48J@EOnBOz5QC6DOuq8NslbCLSGYE7oE9edkekYasIcAZSvO/0@cO9bYzwEFGTUI/pMh@YJlUy5xxva2pjrOVTM6OPlwi6eNg2AsdFM2T/6OhkYQHxQYftoQCLjL4oxHtOCUIJoNlNvbQ3ohQXRxzNKHC6xiNF3HBH9e47hUZZx3NNIAGBinjGgDQRaW38hkkaorgOv2tTM6IH8CRoZ4scEuZWFwaQCXvjYsKEB6cCb0PShErFm90gfTO2YIouWh6brxtgPuMWhQs20YxbA0wdoAVBfIUAmekNuc5dsX@EdAI34J6bRokWEWR8HhomGEjew5wWqfkRGKJMv1uxa8gBxdiV1/hXCLOXgFb8mD2PaMNAcoqJi4qNAQRlp6kOUiD7KHKp1Q5tzJ9eLD37x5N0REfpR2pgbBYQPJ0qRF@ZjPQ4BTus6InFsIa7GkgeCLnncglrzRiswO1EmrV7cV5Q0EUTjbUhHju2swArEjPAiyHIIrQvKjM9QdmhWxIy0uXhLdYRiezHEhN0Z9KTjseNCy2CiZ0bHFmiVxbgrMMlTUY@RFsm95Q4WOo4kdvs@9oUQYWxpwAvYxLClgn2lgbwAUcZMZpB8DksxlmHa6imuIH/ntANgzAQ9qm0baKJp7owhgeJBJw0JzYjpuiAMz7CrYD1R2KWIlE@hZ9B6PZSvSA7a7q8mLiJH70@65vSqXa6jp/ja4840l/TRJHdB9YBGlEr2vWS6Rv1pzFgQLzljX6JR2ZUHQAokQpWn@mDlQ1fxAATNs5mtp/ilJsZnCT/x@2U@DQ6MyDQ18gkYDFdzh0YEMs3oFNo1faqRAXTiggBXAf1oTjBAEjFAc0HbgEYItmal0utq5BKkh0uE6T4zSELDRBHzUVqG3YvSCgiBeYmXV2RJeK5OHUKsb8MSIDgtOe0klgj4gZSgEXnwkKSgh0UPqvOxMKrdMM@JTUfmSIopJGlyEanA0AGkaGZMUEFM3fQ7gdJy926ovmzU68BsoFOB2Oyl43ZtOIQpgqQGYJHqJEEiou8887FtpNJQXgSes9yA8gScWm@QC3/oQoujz3MOgICsnI2cHBI2qOcn5umkd7WibfREIB5bHahOpu7zNQ5UANYa6jdRNblEVbB9k0hVZF6MT1FfY17qixXKB2Cu4aESXA@yEqvhFOYg4NWVJGJRA78FQ@/PdCtQCZgLGjuTRl3I/mkwtBUJomygE4SN9lpLZUiwOTA85Gjv5GE9aIssUOqadnXJw3J0zaLemwjOh3EfHd473jv@emcFDsvsVq96SGa@XMSudjIVBvZEyotqdTOOY4H4fudm3BhxGYbngmAiONOYqjTToXOZhuR8evzVqyQBTQjJQVMAN55XVBoGA0oX19W84ZVOmAwyGUgyihLCEuGQhDgjB2Ydw7UwP0eTt2@x8q5mahz4Y86sicYQhJ7SoR3GEzHwigIWBnX7rEekcUEXNW2celi44pBhfj5G3flqZqhCHWOZj58@ODiuU7TB6JpAQSTPB11Kc3si8Lw1AUN8FQyIP3DpJCMuMo5aNc3rSgLr@hKBF3VL1uAHBGjxiA4RrFFYNG8Ied@/WjbqK@gRB9BniuGqXhnXh/Qvm9FYPrCL09HwXdWL0oBFZxV5reyxotDlbksvFIxSvhLvtvRFmr04UjpNAP1AqDe6EHTqCegjLrTIQK0Osv/s0bWMe1SJBFNACHPmWUSkaXkWh9aLYJKkJ@2DneZYhviCSjye8GlJSoYzBaLuURM0Bn8wNf2UnGZ3JQ2wkPre3qF6PwQOBq7peAY1GtAix57J7eMsn@4Bj9iO5QwcsgVxmHYYJghq09pi7g0c@1oNaeiJRU3gRCHIXxy@0cbQ15hvqflIY8WNVjblqNneOUhppZhDIlEKUVQShRdfa2cakGtR7meHnx9AJ6IUZDlyy/QAEsTiUHKhS4/5Ug8iQEJikJ@VBYwmEK@19jBAiM3gYaEDQRdF3FsEr/SkElOUVsKvzNInzjWKv3ZmV1gLfBhrgSNGssMnR48Onxw83vus5auFwtJzXq4UgXCQXhd0IXHI6IatdYs1TSwWoktA23CxeYEUmICBEs4fTTwXBLeIICLLwBquYVOvqU@coZ300lcLc46hwmtbZyz0GBsfAw0igqHds9AYcdmcNfbnyD9D3x97VUmCVj6cdEUwWqXXumNpA4nGg47BsiQFTZfDpzi64a2KAZnxZgaLwYa4QHWY0XFEzRo5YLzQmW8UDSTF0NOxK8scDMEWxulxw02LEQfT0kg9sBDAVpaislEBTJ@AtsE9rCeesfZHilpmfK3Ial7iQ7Cl5g@wG30DTKcU9FZAivSVR9K627pLZiClEdNVJAkibtFBDo9gX2ARUCTp2Cna@SFxqLTAUVOUFZRGbyY4pgtSSirI@ZJSLEhgloGZBjqrgCNvwkjz9aHgOwLgE5w@HTeIcWHf0zW7L24FjjCzoPfdgaLmmi9bLbsNCnrrLs0bzkQ3Z@2m0k7XyPUoWwF8ugbcu1Q85N3QA3iXOoE16Z2skWc97bo462m0dfWI5I/GQZ8jjMnjPVCk3jogr3tGvO1hBCkeKG0twUoI/E5aMSBkYVQOL0gpCRoU9LTAehLmSwClF9VD4ByQW7EIZDGaESlMM38I8iNHUvvUlb6u4aJ3LpAay1nBoWFxPAORR4FQaAs5zFAYQBMcMwyYlSSYQKjxYHiSZYEtNImJMrT7semZTtKjkzWoWuGwrTeGeqSj3jp2FB4OVPrQQUeNDzsK4C/sJ8i5kcQBfc1jw6YQKVh4EMYHczHCQKcHoqFxO1pqAXxIY9ERAhBewNo4fjtcDHfiuAMwOyRI84TjH6DE2HQaYwCFhMisIHusICwl6rNcpFPbObcRW9cgZaFr@mzWwZm4OAFv9uJlA/CcymAAGy1crGuhM/VdQ2fDvSwyLQXYoRoZGSMHRzNAwaPSyKBF0NgsP5qjHg6dQ8uWBZy6BPwC2d0HQaobbMhKGKEdB1x9QJK@K@0Jn0ua8BYa1A3qHRY@VsVBpZ@EBFhec0EHaoJBWKogOSMK9IIO@WDgvVDjDlgLOYvX6s7YsK@ancwoTaVrdG1EMslmoy6SGxsbyWqykcyCawdc2@jaQVcGXDvUJVAXwonoojGy1IWhTRoD/drJeTPEPE23kQemqLy8NccprVmt5tpZrakEdxXvaagKoDxAC3gDPMl0vY7OdJpvnOPkEZgQsbLvI@88011zHJDgE9BJ2HO8efFB83KNGprHN1NkVHfBbjVQy025yVZTbrVbF61epjVPZjF2uqbVwUQF@emnRuLAdSZj0B2b@aoA4jXdzFXbtW49KSe3UqmyYEFCWjp9p5zOaIzWqaQBPJVqtZJA0oA6TX3oUnzTrJpOR4SCfPRNMHQsK5UUL8qQfjfdTmeSEDedzELPUE8mgS505tOjhcZBCcZED8wpkBIaJvSy8ckNKqPpLBk218@N8XDmxgGigT9Q9HEQf7GABtcZYUcSF9RvWfy4Trk02BCq3gwO9GscP0SVbTxjHQzHctqSlpZrhV3/mdAfOb4mfSqC3SbGeuzkRlISBOiMaQjDRIv92PSwCWu24Uy8@GDnyjFYTB18T4YTEJbhmrkscJU55gx96JDk5i5gJ9HEEwp@nEMT2ExciKCni3CiEEXFCGdtQMGhq5xMkIt0fRgdGFJoJpjoCacHCsXxGzFKrUbjEBkTMge24xoCkARicHRJF10cyDXCCfJDOvh2rfsJQmmvil2ZaYBEfGA5GqUtE9exianxKBbfHmCUY6PHWSA/@iAeRVYXrtGTtjg6Xey4Q@ghoDQoidWotkZBgOR4457oTyEql8I@Px7IDEzQe89JT1XVol7oV8Mw5Aog9hAqCQ1jG6zsMEhQIDAdVPIBG5kKhwmePL1/wIZvaH@PPTwO5XVGTm8Cqm1guh0b9iBLDoCfTNsZmUCGMP7bU@vYcXw20AAP6waHmN1ujiaWRoedro4M3RhPd7qORUejboq6gJ@4nmZpbBwsDN379DGYG89PntXFagxI0s5GN6aNQ6Grk2X0PIxPftKJ33CGymOMyW8WeOy3wuWnKGaCgBIGhE0Hp2sC/zL6j3CxKajlwYAFfYw8A8AKBcQFqLjaLvC8UOQ5@q819yI4hcIxHXWRqwtFpf5nfr@/5J2j3qcCiiBr4Z2n3mwh6pI5Gs9SgQHhqtQlmDiiIoWJFqeuhStROLacRowmMR9Hqx6GhhXOYh6DZoIzddC5W6g/gX2E1gBbQGqAMj/GCRkqonGaj@ig73rXtFVoVGOBQXOJDdpQoBOTUHXhNiUSDLPXaFOxnWB61GPi03GzbARnu8Gm1dF8c5nlKLEJgM0OoNhu1MIVfuvAMKVkMgKjWGneIAYtJl1JcK2o0boQj47rczRKjfMksFymqiy0pqWD9mVS8igZ@oRvtaZ3ZPUzMIFwqebmXWlg1OiiqjX0qoUhyUBX7c6IAJodQrExcn0I8oRkpsukhPqZ2H3H6glsQg4YhjBTDisoWBURLSENVgobphuuHqXLd1lUlKOxhafX8F6p0sZ1gNhS1QgRNJ8LcnmaPbskTejazkRvbJl@m8xF3@kMg6VZ9tVFrUzXdF1t5nHBopo62Tv@@NOm3GYYuJGGk2xlVovTcG00KMigEOHCdXDh0iDf9GmPT5c@mFheRYRMTel8DGQfcLAEaiRKKCgRZv3SuFyUpW@AUZwyMOfebJQlRnou9i3N9w2b8Ryb6VxPbjYlFSRTp8nvBPMbVSLTSSDQQE0MgyzWyLOT@wfHxyJwrpdKHuBkURWao6YPQRFZV@iQkvHCV8mdXpLcwThpHCHgoKmBldEJ4gNT14Dpwc6A1FF2DAw3BZ5pnOfRwZtOrdGITBMLCIQLvHSf0ihCljLSUCaKrLoy/89tZlIF@awCx2coJYHcqbtVoK2ZFie2@Ub0oEOh@imABEYp9Av1zRSVYptKOljBN8JZarCkqHIIJWg2ifAWpBwA86TdrrHlBgCLhpY7QOryPK0KuoS@roRVXwdvUF0ohiB6/R152ZSFSjuzuQoVXc0WrH5n5Y/hRQzLqD1jZbKbKdrerzVklgc27cgk93NqNl953aNKNpmDZ8PbFDxcoUWFDl3Qtbwwa3nZFzQyFCV01AcLEoqERPBuQsCzNJxKfrBtMBr1SKXJRUR0FUlOLi8pDcmmSigNwaUQVhnz0MoEwfTIgdI8Ct5LiGsBtLUGa1awzbY4PjSnlieFMYSp6tLZFS1UOOPj8ZgWaNqnDp1ailwdWVQKqPlFsUen1vWYuOqVXpZAozwwWHVd7rxRt08vKwDoDEswd0896Nh9oPOCsqhJx/RGh/FXpLy8XmUp2WA9LO1pwU2EN7dACpUyBe53u@Y6UCACLkQL7yvAQEghP6tiXlTCFx1wyAX6IxBczEpZFP3qUieyRPdg4W5w/6/f6AH9r9fOEDoKHOSMHB3ourGmhP7aygqi4gO9rK5YNhY/sUyNEoa6bkOpay4USbMix2rUdL5fEKD7H@HsRVDjwJt4Aa3xBjZjOWeTj@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@V@cP9QCRdJKEW5RUKF6o9jK8F9rVw/ldzT2yqIviHp4lLamPOGLnaVmArmWNaXDgwDnKBbXbIHcpnGFCU21LcmYZxaOddm4f3n6DrWkTbsOsYzqk6DdocRKmVw@C5TsX@e1PI3p9b7MKF0DW3ptkLEKvfUMqCzotdrVUpUWfmSMRRZ/nAR1bcmxsRYaWg87b428J3@G4yMD8@UHBRjMxiRx0kAfBcmgnobWIYflGvsp/HpRmGiWaZu3K7KLAu1MWjfYzSdj8BxhI7rMQb2ZLxUq0vWmX18M8mG47BJO72l3GHIl5VD5Vs0pSX93DPoeaPFxCw8XItWL8iyHCgwsZmVpYebLKlcFPe1ya5LCVOfRcoLWJxNc2PO1WlQssRXO64VQeo6w54CVyqSbdqGP8PrB0rTruNYX6amQKjiG8oOWKsCXdV7U41dU3eC91XIYujCwwGPbn/doAXrbQLbEuiDRvNNlR6f@vmg2hRwcnOEE0/Lj6vTwGFJSxt1expJdc@d9ArVcykJfJUWB4TYIl9rvSIZDIUoYlks3djkmHrqdA1LY7dpMX8TvoqYuxHfssQIZmRxBpfN2y7m2xNXJNJ4BpQye2CiDI2RQR9vUPG1Hm7OEdzWAk0dPNcFTw1Dl6YHhr4OYGyCULDxujRRHNOUfMcG48rH9YRopFi4YjXwXSd@wym/lUQ@HGkDg@0Wc5OYXIxW4JIZZtMtnKvHLapsmYwO0RbbgKxnCWhRp8bMC@8rET6e6VCvk9HtY21XWr6OA6Af0NTXLZW93r/aQ2doD40hW58ePa1rHMCPPtvd56asQ64HQ1wyNx4vLaWP09NyLOtD6IlykUlJx@mvzNMBvmqLb4h9Kbzsvf7gduvIneYz2YGOta1maEygU/Ic3xkbAn1aB2rhKA@7rhOg4Qz1zzt8dKORDxQJ7z8v/lsNy4Hm@OMxvXXG1sSjFxpVoG9I36Y09dn6E7r40nEH4ltn1BUDTzFYnELnv1eLmK7p60N8RZ1xtjFwuvrQvC3TwbYYUjjewx4/yHBFyphEuI/eomUCed2ZiPxSj4c/w9vhukoPho5YzxY5blBWVg3P0ZfAhbF2qntsKBRdpIqjwbHWyF4Vr9KX7atvJqa/QBpbsBSN7bI5CXSsy3uwdGKtWkXfxViI4WBJxVoupRo6auOCIYO2o6xLdnkxW6yJ5XLssi5D8VLSHMUWpXwZcgcLfOjQoBkbtAX/Jf5aWpm0spOzh5OBd11gsrH6HuhneFk/ZkHXTMfGq6HP0uzgto7MqiXhy5Rw74DCNTFunFAp3DijQuEUS9AcE24duEHVTdYOoFnm2GNXIvTXzsMFC5bAEL86WchoM1ttSQcV0zP6bP4DXbdpoSPHxeXGoIMIOk6j4/A5CnOmeDHBZTsDEOqCRRbAIew6tWXlGqHV1R/1mcJnT4yBhguqH5k@rshcwRWUZVetLboV99cmmmd@bQIlW8dsuD8Em4N041sI4NMKfI@1gak/XKqIKJMBgYPlnOy2xP7odb0uzoemh8uZIscNo1LIcoyJkes6YDSsgLw6aB9tjbFoQOx1y5XQqwbWnfEM30qbUddNY@qmT4dYg/s6u3HdCrAbM3E@GY0nXnBbnQe6YCo@BD06pf7euQnIhTcgWslQs/zVw9Sx8VbQwoJOceFcp41/blrOgHxelgkobaCEoXK@gnHuQfd8hKtxXHsFJ9K0P3DOE0c5BJcV7A3UrYEvT9imf/NQju/jypzwjoVhPQe@hiA9wqu4@2UxCCerKfLodl1/8Qr0Lf07cN4zZ@LqBjqjfU3iZkGQqrEfLjHG1zYc3JflPG6l6Y4FzQsc1somozv2xBfciX1jr1C8sVeo4t5WMTYgqa8dPH6ejnMDXZJ9mxYa7n62cK1dLXCFyUwbFLH1cnQZOrQl7rNdmY7peuBb4uzh1lE6Fdf3nVX2ztEMOpAPNphA@E9G9w0d5wxvTfuJ89ixHeiNxiAoR8cG21tgaZXH6ogY7RG@PQ/06d2azDOKdk0nxLQNbWx0oX6thetD@iKG@L7ma2u6IjowSO2/yHUrr5hW13Bf0xG/mHudSbucoYfGlNoW6xmGtUHB13WmEuNg3FIbWZqu8caOY7MrlbYy3JTHN0sV6Aro5cNnyUVcbb80LrDSPlsu6tMztkTE6LHNL9aV1TW6jsWuNyxIsk22IEBzTcOTHuFeCtSvmCcCaF/ejTKkdKMMWZhGoMmeaR6doV9taixQKtMvsf5nqLm6g9NggeOGpTmxDRBuEdPRAn62aqALhJ@CxNL0SbA16W3ZskbdEb2sNRhitXlsdPHVny7dNcTXptcrk40MBVsmxJZzRRsNhOIKG3WRpI7AGknf3m0t2VHLVDXH9EIl9dq5crpSR7BNQ3@r4aiZQ@m1GJheCocyS0@oc81AdawZ0SFkSaNv1K9sScvr1kChsQzBH7pg80v@TWPb4XYuKyZDJiMDZ5iXp2DWqq6ON6SFdVZPpkfC1TWEYGdBkCXRLoNMPxT21mqeiB7@T@99IkEn3Cnmwy1OQHTdPn0PmZ@4dnD7EA48cjy/b06fQr7xFYB14gSLVYAocGMtA11b6woBtWdPLDb6MIgtuhr1qDkm0P2fBcGi4to3BMM@E@iGc9PrJXLYm13SHu4V7Bs9IdhvAacZhEfhS14RWHBfMXsal4240lORGGGnxXyw9nMVcc9DyQD6luMLY4/epbF3dPjo6Yk49pSV/dPeEF@NuKbHLW3goJbl2JDUa82NTXaytWg90/Ole88UYf/RoYgAa@jNZjQEuOG03NJt7bhnuGespK21gjDU8FcriA9PHj/KLN7DJKn9oeuMjHQ8eP/Zsyy@ZvLJs5XB8dgPoHX0nena6IcHipJewb7PbTo1uE56rkhpHaYTA6xRYMaHbP@XW5Ur3RkbvZPZ2PgUOk@U4N4HJl9cW8gn2pk5wFZIKmsJRRsqqYjFfDq2LBuMbcON7uvq89Qco7TU6U1it7VrUVBzyElubrX2cNN0/1UthsjBMoQvF0mRr3NrfNdiSfP@rhlTFGUdnZ9pfahXUlhbWcsAqyaHLefsA@aRjcB4ESIvwQeuEsxbF5GXhBGIbgkvODwfeIKzu3YNzE0IIu/iygZ/btgzzRboXNZN6kUVYuOKthtBPjc@YEIqWt5zhlujr5zji9bTk5ROnelbEj5xY1H29@8d3hbhOKDlzVAfP3lOjjQPNzu5GTCeY@MDcrzQjF4LOG6FO@2tnU7tuYBKvRHfYLy6PVfJM83tOfZsevskHH3RFLt2uhlthAufKJBhmVNzVV@ls3Gto9VrjG5Lm73B4cyW9OD4JjgBovff/peKIst0iyO8KzJ7vKVmwgZOUujSZrhvXjzo5DASDTrqLSJ4pFdao4@MKa5FYaPBq4z6lf1b8Ya@r5Re353cFFa@ISx/Q3rXwtCT5ERZuQFh4YYwUhCj4EeOdT50xH3NNbwVK0BWZuimglRuKEglJp2DvdnpxGLgXq/i43sLwW0lt54YvpsfD52umV9Zhr0@bmZJHuPW7NfDg@UUmkuXtwyc4H0P9rw6vfOJsTKhx9rb1QFU0pyuDAIhaAwn9H2I68HLE6Rd0HkNe2CyfRzJPcc/oE83GGbR686r1yKY4/uT8focg2zED2BcFedLgC/AZnbOPXIP34tbqOkrbH9cHLfaf51OS6KBQdzO9OHJXshdT59JaizFRS4@O1ryxjdH/afPYn6uMZ2uM3qF6TobcmXIItUnJ/mlZLcbL89WEGv9y0agboA8ju5r9SAm7D55dl0koPk29EdWGPKJZi9GTJcqrOf49DXDlYFHsyldQ7mypodsCduqMFe/bf0YdMimCWl7UqeDey51Ouu48sT4jM49gBpEfKaWMKTB7krGND8Mc0ijrG2ozulC@VnK7rPx0LSnK4NG6@LQJaSp197qZrBHnlnOOXkUbR20Tjyoq5FrZ4a9TjitelNRqORu1sJyV1SqdfXCvpUS3NZVyb11itoVmYELIm6SJhj/WJcehA@fqulb4T95FoLfDrtvOTh@3zMno9uBKdpM5nZA9wbxdxWheTsYflrkdOi49u2gITtVq/eMD8zExgdDjma68wF56Pb7twMdeM7tQI8nlm@izbIa9IkzsXD7gFVhB@5gpX9ju9FqiVVxXSDu2u4N3fT6cFwX6Uw8sIHMSHhGEYXXpr/kGfJM3A83kTds0XbSV/B@4pCv4nbxK0jx9gPr6JMH6@CWJ2wmOMVPXwdeONe9Gjqe5W5t5G/NAX34kEZnm6MbYRf7@h26js2e0uu6x8UefytSeqhZ5q0CLVzwoN6y9AE7NBZOznK3Sy1QEB6sr7NPZ9OFublceovtOLEqbF8Fogx0PR1@7wjXpSu52KAfW39meOuH/Wjv/7WDkaZ7IaOhF1teEE4ge@s0gfgIwnKH/uzJvb2TF0ePVoZ@VRt1V0v68KMg6v3F3nhrFdtomJV@REV6hlfBG2qgVNERVgE3v7gyI/9i79HR6j59CAYt1Cfuehobll50yame62mjSn5FDbL9GaCHj39GxMsGu7Cx/UzYLhKeGH7rJZWyQRCklz@vF98SAzfbT23iZtObdPsLgL28JBvBlhMQwIebWASbbOCetKY9MXCXDPbRLb@@CcnU60qhQnbwe3ZVosg0TfxcZ4Vt/Rkm1iSbF8EGEtWqMicbdcJXeRJs4RHt5M92owfEuI82FIoIpwrZ9CFkM9x@gtDPK5FLQgfOBR23K4YnUYpvxFMLNuiAPG1eHB0eHTw72Tt5/qwpt@fBBh5hKWwbUgu3CbqT6/FQ@IBuYJCzb1PQjWMsSI5@UwcH3L2wXAQ/J7dctPpS0RaF4ncwzuaFbUsS3cNEEuaQP4FnqdFQVCvBi@EOS0wrKNi@psq2E6G7okAdMdQ8TRMqrUrkVQmPNTAuN@0g/OrXF2kofqmzit/qxISDzwkAJw4cpxek6Bnk9iNM8cHe4aPnxwckzOCCa87Nnj@sVwrsaxNsXyWop75J13XXSTKIkoS6qteTD5JAmKSYJFW66wz90gMwOoCF1MH9aoLYWyS1SfEDBZNRpUj/9RvSPCni@0lpgE2GmUpCssDzlFE2NjbICTAJuX98@OnBMcH8H9yn3kgiREFOcMuLP/1xj30rKdx6LvxKqTsKLEGoLc8xe1Xch0Y3SCKvqMFmVj2CGzCyrVqIMaXfHaKcR0fHYt8tTdONwbj45jnhjjKLTW@w5qgEiMdk3zSim8lEH1OKvgnHcfSLW8Dv53TD2ys7kabp5oDsm6zBRrEhasp64XdZcBYdN33Fvsn0TNzKBuuhj3uwLjcSXHhLtz4WyR5@wBU/E6vRz35BZie2z/Y5DHZBSwCHipGsypJNmln2kTA@Bpjc3oBG0jUGpk082wT1xq@S18DBOFNdZVsdCUIjeS1KiLpKXQIapDHAa5u2elLLld7/yj@XBjUCbh/c3wncU/kePP1S8NQH9y8z90sJGfT6Jq@LvMQzhHtDByVgGeH65s9@hp9v5lObinLacc8yyYJcg4tSK5ACubPZEoTNplzf3dSAkP6baQuas7SVPzPuD/u9w4HU4nnQZfKStHVxcZF8sHVkviyQotAz1eKb6WyeK@beTOc5pfzmdKwUm@KbaZsv17On7VazTY6OPnvXeZfmp2ezN9DvpIDB9p/ySp5PVCvkYqeYS5xW8LuQUMJT8haO0z7BP3W/7cXcGrq7feDbJE8SrRZ@h5kv8SD2km34U0nxCg4mM5oNsSHutN@9Szc1zZ9C122aY6/Xg9MZkpSqpp8RaGp3oRGxCBJp0TslIhyF0bRPpnvGYDA50Gbm5IG/K5bEsqjGBNP2489fBEftxfPnhDwnz5@/PV4jxtqZTEoQmtQ9DT0fQe@dnZJqRysk8MuOf/qTjXn24qiz/affHEnGBt6e4u0788fofqYU7mxs3Ll3L5/PqqrK3EefH319b28vfz9bOGoWdvKCvLH9J3@8saGq26q00fY8pZ1snp5@xqtynhf/9EfJztHR1zyvkfs/v/GuoeClBJczUiIVPHJEASdey3AqpFAgH3ok3iYUOBIz@uskQv@LDaI0dkr/7XtP3yT8REOVXrhw9xNvEsVygjnBAU@58Oks0UhsI1hxnphJ9XodnKX/9u8hfuMTwIMhs224NAohruIs0RDqNMplolEEh6KqkO7//Y1vxHII8gxESZ22yPDYBYHYbPL5ksrvtOHYosc2hzuACbIkhXC2P/QNhyjlu8pdfDDhAW62gVsmG34rgd@2fboLkMfNTCbTFjsCHOJL2r9IiqK2FOUuiF/hzla9LkC/QpttLle4i/uxpmlvOHB8hxh3XywdiRd/L8dKNLUXf5/HMdk3dcN1slyiuLH76n6jAeXNNXJbjQw9gkZG21upzDvOLsiak@HENR38SG7tEQY1eLms8tlsdrfDGssU6ShMw0aTwINdE4nIB5szueLXQEnQJpE/i0Wux32VbEIbab9aD5c4wOPP/rc/@/6ffY/@vk/P/4Tbp9k9sy9tAdAZNJcGHLvVqt5o8A2Xv2jhcwN4TK6Wq2WpM2@ltpqN9jGotR9fJgu55DP6RVoF02ilW00av0GTbQTJ43MjsfBuMJ9G3C8IYMDUA@4BpUhimWrUHVGNkCtwXCJcayY0zxptAccu60JTKRbaAovV3IXK4dVShe@0E8LmDCSR2m6oBfUp2W2wgww3PeJgbnJqMSxIkN/GomyLkMVTI@6VaITRGguYLwsX5KnCJZpNqW3QvqIRZnR3o7pRrharqtRprD9qixh4UFDDMI68xFkiOmok4MOQnomIM2N@L@M1EVULCRmYLMW9BQ7qCoQGtAz2X3PQ6soVFb4WuNQOT2rAH2pOUAcdXlb4qLFRqwGODfjRPxzRI143qE/gTUGuHxukqmypOalwp3igYtd79XCFZiOzTZt1u5ERUUwK4hUYDvoSone73bd6FzQTTetquqb42kSbajPN7066066vT3T89jk5QvWuE5DBzTkFp@yEVBGFRK6gbCbuYtlyagU/Iw62Sbmcq6i5kpIrFXMlWS0XcuVKrpTPlUqAMFdSc5VKXlVzxVKuWM4Vi7liBT/VDjBFgMkhhlIhV8lxiXfNDXLM5NuUZMKjlbn1eC6KncBJHQ6eguBME6A44S7hXOIf4GgoqkK2oHOU4QIaIXUSlf6ghPuaOfGyHEmAsnfRfrfVfLdF4rUlBHmGm9jZbWeE@bwJ7lot@G83ImeNHswFRW3PM5ntlw3QgV42mhlA@TJAKQqEIhU7DdLepkFRakFyQfh2G9QoIbPd3K47@/QUaVMU2oByeymbu7uUr3YhZmMTmnw6k9kUhA3smZtBbwTAyH1BeQBTOwW6ysXFz3mSZN5JFp3d7W0QK/PteWPe3J7Pt7fhv02v8@AOvvPta396WxxrYBbhbRRJrabUaEmtQCy14VmUGugjSi1wNOAOcM2cWm5jR4iKjtj@x/kXs4tr5INZbouQay6xRbYSuGtYLrHFJV69/@J/wbP1/ovfQ6WVwM@ocokLQriEtFUh1I/eKqC5PbbJY3bY4MYzfEQf9Gg8Rk@bXWw0hSXplUiqAvugglIupkXs6TtOv4PvIovkFYAC2MHAgPYSilnCq@Ui38koM5UktvliiUrWX7h2JJPJf/JKrZSSzNzGl2lfeZ73OJbLRT4BuKbKiqBcNthm0Wz//l9YdfyTX1h3cInLCkEapQijC5cANkpIEpiJXKKxPcLFlvg5IQG/C3lW/0x4vifgRzA0n9rjOFgHWkH98KBeqTTQTjI2j2jT2bq/BVcF/gcbUAjS6gNoq1/XR6CDt/q5gtpCs/RjDcxzkGlC9w3@Hr3FHznR8Xf8Bn/k5C3@jn38kcdd/J28wd9eF38nI/zde4O/x2/x93yAv9ZXcjmlxm9eUPJklIoy35zylEw16M4ara/47qxKv4nBqzsq6JzBR0lSuXwlnWh9hQ2cVINPeOACWEP3a1q9UuvW1QA0WL2DIaLphR8dTbH3rasqSeOARa5ScFwBp5rhAh6ZXEVx3ORPv/vNbybr9aSQpJ8zyIOf0EWgLgWCR4iZZznBz8RB/qDSPS9Z201@pUkHpwqVdhMD2xDAJepkU9lUZEvWZaWrdMFhEtkl8lAeKj2F2m2yQeSZPCPyyFF64DLgJ4PLlPtEHhDZlm0Ag1Bw@R3ZR1cfbgP49QGRCz8TVzF1FVknkJCFeir9cpvSwZjyZYd8PHQ8PztucU2SJPwrAwxwURFlsWi28aMTTf7Vq5a01VYrZSIik4ud5qtWss23eNygWK3kSXdmbLRe8aCVyDxrDOhDEp4HVn0tIbVaEqsAIBut0fm80zl4cr/TkbB7bBGjkdnNgLjf3a2D@A9uO4lGbadVpb1H2IMkpO2dViMnoLuYgb5BBT/y0LAMOytlvuSxQAz3xgYlQPvV@SswglLnaAqdn8HtPHS8aMGlw4wkGiydv2jFHqkDDoSVpBcrMCw5INe2OwOFZ6H7wR@syX@ov/mP6//4OUmTVLOdTl3Mt1P0SOMvnb6YX8yDayOdSgUPqW34oQc8Y5SLeQOdFOgCXM1Uup2ez5kfXFPpbYawAclsN2jcBRx0MokoSZosu6T@fu@QdHC0kjXyit/edvXLVo1Kg7xcIQn@VY1oi5mGVmsqy2mQWMHu6YJNNrVLOiybrtFPZG12m0r7T35Ed8jfSVOgQr5WU7YIe1Dzaq2WD59K5VqtHD5splKV60dD3lGKYDvl8@l0rQYPOyFaGR4hbpO8y5A6acG1ffcuS6SsXl6GOHP5YkbGGZ5aLUypAMkanqYz8Q166OFTurs8SItCgqBQIMEgdUqmn6dAsZ7kq/zdu6ngK847e@m7d9WKfHkZ@YzH4KUseXU6PdPtdNA/d3nJd3g6O1ApwLNcvrxU5EpGSZK046ae4EeyIK2UoJA7aoMmWwGZreZLEBzkoLC9Xcw3GsU8@BTLEBEKxSR2jST5ZI1PXNBiKOUSk2N8Db1JAho09JrexTxBa5LkC@kUyMA0aJXzBP5cFJesuyoU0rW8LCcu5jwDVioVBp0m@WKqnKkEv/pGmjRAZWI/1PtymfxWaWsXNGj8edNVB0rU2oVRV@b1C6OKXyOa1/TgQ6f4frZx926uAqQpywlyf4K7RGRbXCCO69AxofYFlxaXTGbInbscvrzuJqu1XVqzSrlAEska8xSSINZJGWgsqVsFpYw04cw@7roAKgRHB0TIBtngVHrHC1dhFuoGeoLtG5d99M/14CA90iUDPMgAbU9iEosexCIsnF51PQJy2BGERo80Lh6RjxEdbMg9V8gxLk2SRxPdxGGvo0d7@wcnWXVbIAn1wd5@Vn32/F5CwcfC4pkG5/D5@GDv/tPnEOHo0cHes4OPDz89eH4E/h45XxxRLxH2FVGfEXOteD4nL7jX7lvNMDRjYhid88nk/A15bZodE6rWmkDZnIFLPKMDRRpri@LV4NRNT3v9WnPH9CDvf/jt9z/8797/9nff//a33//293/6xfe/DeeP4fwuu3/331UKeP3pF//yd97/1m@D53@C8w/h/MlPv/j1b7CTPv8RnP8l5vdHwRmDYycHuH7pp19870c//eKXfwDnvw7OH1w/f@Unq8/vf2v9ifG@9zs3w3z338P5uwxXCPvd32J@eL8G/1sM7pd/8P7X/gP7/0nwQ@dvv/@1P8JL8PAvfvAn/@X9N/@jqpb/5N@@/9b33n/rm@@/9Z333/qn6vtf/7eKHL/8zvvv//5f/sHv/uUf/I/0/2N6/d0P@b//wb/48//1z//3P/@D4PwJnP8BXD/58/8IzfVvfv@H@P/e7//NH/4Q///zv/mb3//Vv/ml/4k6foM5/p9//e/Y9a9@5T//9W9@5y9/8o2//tWf/PVv/P5f/h@//H/9@n/@q//@9/7qn38TPX/jJ3/5h7/0F9/89l9861/9xTe/WHP99o3XLz7A/4t/AJ8Pz@eH4PmQcn1Zny9@rvz8XaixSAX4BLj7n73/9V8EBv81Qt5/@8f4ngOca/4/VhUK82P29P8Dh3q9zBgigwvOX33/7e8iif4HIBH8I3p9J3pYCmEP31k8AFl/c0Wkf/bTL/7Vj@hTwqg26LQU9uRltZzZAqNnq1IJevNgxgqi/OIytghBkNJ3UEIthX0HZdv7H37j/Y/@6fsf/sb7H/4S9uFCvpLdywrKLdN9AFj4ADgELH4IHAJ@Bul3MnQUT8h8Bk8bnxXKOdu2a5999hnXuZTwhZrdS/IZ/Mhn4UFYEL5wEwSFYeiPb@AQ8G@@etXGOeKYn6Qw5JLK7kEQrv6BlAT1TmZHUlQWZFxKmywWqYFHrpxrxbIu9ftbVfgRuFSrWxdZYacFiiCNOueMsEhKgHVDIoqWzW3lNACU8gyOVO1dOZ8pbWkaWLcZxJuhqtBWqKAVcmSaCZKcBvPI6A9A0y3qnBI2FTClwVNuSqeb4V8ipExyhNjsX@NIhmpN9MCvjoVO6gjihVPV1MkVIJnMYqKBaoyEKWtbzIdOwNN082ChZBAmMwWLHBw4Og5B98AgqNczGLHOsgiPrDCNMqFZyWTqUG6MzeJkO2VEMb1HsUDMeuaYdLbqUxYxg/gaITkyHHod84rKZ8r1@5BgfXqfIC5ETtG@elVvlOvTBqJ7x6iTmWbu0Twhsnpm2ngHz3WKE@JxifvvICvleibTKGOCWEhWPWiEYyUVaOFo2TMkE9QB3HEJ1s4uIXd4pcyzOZYNJBiDxmtmAY2AAA7hrcxWUBz6D5303KIE36BJBakQFr5DVeUdpj0jAOAVBFEUCZy4sGGH7ELwlKHK0GThlmEYMpQjKAdEHoTShMvQ@mUEgvTBm358lahqvgbWR42gl6tz@L02ulpG5januBLqggSashx8dnTOaQCTl3PcxaUWrJTa1MgcvIocQtA061tf@sDMIrE2Nze5RIPP8U9FWjWSRNzTKl3vBi2X2lFVwhcrPHobdPEfI95jXKqd5ai7hsUk77/xo0ReLiW4zST9ajZhCZE7GXbu7m6RO0BWeo/5TemyMiGTc/JOgpFxO5PhVUi04cDTFiVhhmLjXpJEHf/gn6CMRRLkSHNNL8tlqUjMwk2sJzCYPH36NMgv9XhZ5zLQ4tScgs84LziZTCC60cM5@GxWFLNiNhvcRXqnHmLgEGlocBc3kfQkbu8ppTJ@29XWh0gX7t27d8AbHNKieggGOHOSupov00BC2WCKC760UZZjOyxY1ixcV6rmKxwbrSBKMU9IinIEHGmCCyhTwNppjq3CYuwVHqmkWgaTGiGhxsQUgDE0RQVlElupSl@4IYXS0iPkLP6IY5Bs3BsXB0RLRFn@UuVCOgzcf0r2nz5@fPDkZNxuE86gXxU2OmPX0Q3PS2HY3pP7jH3VSjGdaDax7CdVFWUkd1CVkY0zh/ePD59VCaNYUHUpWo4anVcP6FJRuMR4/GI74eLYu2vw@MEsh3@G1@qCFCm1AvI7nWhwCd1Aowz4FP9w1sixMUD2fewN7jlTkpKzPJ9Vimgyp3GaGLLzdWdCcGNHtgsESAdczSdCeTHnjQshNvuEHg1yrHLMISjUQXKVcugoMYdSKiLAU/bFuRzXeHZwAphPnhJFlUVy7HRNyFTjMzIVaT6PnZHhZIU5jY0S6cQcOQhh1S3DHvjDTfxuL9@S@RiBNptyFn9qLgdXJV/MKoVSe2PDuhAQT4uyzAWuVZzD44WANPkIDsJ9xJGPwAsOYU44/CY3CQb5D5/WGPPi@7MkBbl/5ru8UgC5kOZwviLAx43jR22MAnF53o9LbHz@uU8ajYMn94XDBzguMR2ScJ2jYPbEoUj5pjdxDRo6IKRnfmrip9XEnumNLW0GbRjItdUAevg4/5qYz@d9wHn4gKgNlT6yuD28znXq0wX3fKpxBORzn0vcDYdiuNLdarX@TsmXIG/V6rucqnLgwW2BUmH2N4DZ6JqVLYn9eLueV@SMEk50kDTP8zUPMpXLlaUtLqHwPNxyuRxH2w/hqgZH6Eqmd3K9LgQiPq/QhUwcbu@vTetqdASw0zsL2JzMYDEEAsjAd4kchpVYWPAU9gpQFFzaS78mWwsEinz3bg4HpHJ5OSo7oaQhc6jRzVw@h5UEfuDbTuRLwQwalK@d4CzDJ706uBMtLDBry0qCJ/iE4i9XlrlEMwEtm2u2m/X/73/tJtee/uP9A1mazTo3BQEZPwNvhKF3svTjuMfO08X/6dNR/PHG/@ip8/ipM3LgDx3hY5TftcW/Vlt6vPkfCE6USTXQhDnfmAI7wS8vF7h/hAc0cMrEbLp2O9g@skGXVjeVSr59AI2kSdrb4c6SDYDeZi/FENzSo85jESXfDF6UaXiG1RdxwXKd3x43crLKbwd7WDfIp4aNQiiI3@jVe45OP9Zd64kmfjQd38Rh8fJ5vubYuClcPZwThY4qfTGon9OXhWtGfSDiNiOurVkQvev0ZqLnz0DD0B3LcetJsLaSYcACuQFqOA5A7@Ry@SoUTBw74x3Q5T41HUsDbYQD917PsVFPUgulTFORQYfBUyln1eyGsVMqVXuibhmau1OoFspZeIhms3cKcnUgfvb40UPfHx9Dp2t4/k6@AhFwuy7cWGenXC0UgH95PtOkibfxu8SsjxI2NkCoG1pPgDtOdnuCWm5D5J7p1uvJ5E5OUQWlmpPLcy4iKtbHUGnk5fy2BHcwGCWcRIfOtUH2jIGBvSCtCGVbGmMVgxNANXB2wVnYlrrgNMFZ2ZZMcE4aOUXeliasppGiDQ4zlUFKZrG2s0PlIuhfqrZjG3OumtWy5gUlfLXf78@3LjKLB067ENgTVMlc0LLdi@ixJsTgqmSSFcxFIPhofajhi2CNQJVXC2W@1qwtnktFvtaec7sjo2dq@NXqlnxxPVYRun2GNQEJtQg3r7qO41e7Rt9xjQVgTimGgCxD1wHy/DxKriVjihfXkyvGgKYX17HkC/w8ihVmi5vPoVIZvaFFvnzJJbaOP801GsAgF/mSmi/kC2quWCyUVFBVKvlioQyVKhflgqpCS81XypXSHJqIJL1L0C@zkf2LsOlU6fb0Ka3K9ldstkn63RPTuijnBNbWU@kadG6Jd1zizvGnaqOxfiwlBWrfp6rQqOcKFXDl0KXmaFeoqoKaE3KKoOTwf4tDxf@Hw6vwV/EKsXIqd4K7rjwBjQuUTZs8wt0bfIecOA59Q@Weoa@B2B9qdIeXfdfxvL8DzD3NPmVB90221WkU9FDDL5h5I9MfroF4Ph7hhi2G@w@G4WDUhQyiaGUA9@DiWo6zCqBEnh@tKeXjaHNxIAbbXRzAjw8/fngSu58c7O0/5Irk3tMn96/cCgFQgTw6eHASPZZYaBi1EKH4@sGjR1cfg1v@6fPj/sRx8eQePH2eX1wiL3yxh8vDsQwUeVMkwQUfscdGxZJsgIEXOhQO3ym6m6@Qu4GzUFw4ZXS@YG8tmV702hF78a3KnYSvMmn01dGuQXS2Lw@OfNE98wIbVClVOG5MbOeclGTScyxLw8@x9zfAc6h5pGsYaFJZFnIiJn3uuFbv3OwZG6DpQBoVBT99jZngHgKS0USnr3yDTos7sPbwQ@k4v9y1JgaZjMlaT7ihFzpdczCEbv3cCQG4rqYROL/sAfGN@OHf7OGzNKjftRDrOjiX4Paeoq1cSfD8Ps8/1Hyt5hqll6RxMAVOhXajubNsOZvj/QJftQc4H2mN0fr1xs2tCajpGxtgwv/Vb/74b//4V3fUlrwv40Dq40d5dQYahyLVunWiFC8bO3lnF/V5Fw3ErY6RKA/qVa9QVHYk7FTdupzZTYwd76FRrvE8GMogTaseWscP6BfqD2wTZMkDOHge@0/9dF@jXFelthVB24lQSygwoURquKuVcqFcyanlbLlSzheUYqGQVdSsUiqXKpARWSkrxXKhomTL@QqoSvkKhBbAdmYGmCRtkT0Lx1uyzMiStqqA3tbxW8/bdAxAHIKxz1YskLcpLU0SWvQ8IbwBcXiyZw8MC3Dg0I1P36XbMuvQBxNFJrkSAcwa0UniwYN9Gct3Dx9wHde@zPM9fCiUZbl0j@cNGrJfRm2Qd1icMm6gx/vsQZbvQTVOGALce57nh/hwUMSxd5438WF/j9Gxjw8qxgewUxbCHqzwoQRgNj6ARUgRvImwAdgeSydPM3qAD5gkhjxgIfsQxvMfh9nBkGMGxhA8DEu6t8fzh@xhbw9D9mmxCyyjX8WHPXrwvAsP0MZ4fgCOgQutGzgCnNjSeF4Hlz7TwA@/r43bk9u@xvMzRh4kEM9PKbSmn/J8J/THZD4NclNA6lbpg8JKvUsfKvjjeTXMNILlooccz@ejhzyU7eHDT7Wh3zMG7Ji57K5DSR8@zGnmdHLwoPvxx93BoOvO9g4@Psag/f2HoNDMJm530A0idjtwOBBr/6GqnY5mVw8o9WGnU9WslUFf7XTymn0lqDPrGJhDiPUGchYcA0xo1NmHoP2HnV1t1QoUirCDQmYE9y4e90Zwv6d1WVB40CB6n3a7fA2aAVgErRSHtg4uIsHmeQpC286ONN11avg8rROZLtWdNYtyu0YDyAiMFbk2x/B@Cq8aDo@mL2bNaV1u16f1UrACtJ/iW1O1YPLZjdGOUilUN7QdRc1nplV8DdjpJ0lSUHZISrm79ZaknqR3VLBcNvjWzo7AN5X2TrH0EiVaFS87qlKu5mWVpNljrlSFOHJSJgQv6WapvVMqVBeRS6WMJqnVUgn0P6CPD1pEFwckOySVOje003Qas05HtKA8tOBkRgtt1vqpaXZaZ5kks3RtWldqbI9eIl/Blkr1cEP4iY77gBKGdAAIpztyFVcvpXilUuYhD5KUSoMwms/njDgXeTB2Li68i4vWPBKVErgWY4ovvnZyenLyGUgrUFNmWaqJNoLRuCP2ffta8Pjxw33x8Gn4hHu9iw9QQ3ZccR9l3FIIU5VDrxOwe8SH0LeDyRr6QRzfdSzxgC7zBTU7DAi3ShCDfVfFk4dLeJ4NnXOWMkTyanTzPnwBG7fCN3tEqzfApfVIiuaKaOlzqlV0Go16pz4yRmN/BkUMY32V0H3iF2gOPZZ3@ikP3BCNRr/ou84oCOjU5Tl0cdPEVBDIHih9EzcLGDt1IiivRk7vlZrRaz3cC/9e/R6iqXXg3gWj23Bdx@XByORr/R27PrE9rW8cGS6@VX74dBO0HdyUIdUnRnqTtA4Qeh@NpLnQcIm9yOOTySilCY1uetkLR7AjDyRT6mth8S9wBBdyzvPzWr9OUi8B9A08u5sk1RPvpXfyNaDYPdJJg5f8qv@qT1RSzNeoLZRCXNAEKaWQAlq63vgqKGkM9SmpViE3QZWfAlZMDBBDbdAQLT025zW9bpGUQKZpSqN8bVBvYvRLvGwLoFUIQvOyjQPQL9BAeDOBzrMBzb02S2h1b9KlX1MhcldR5WJtCn5KKV8bQn1rL6c1tz6euEbNgsdgyJrQEms1oC2QENC8vUy9/8VvpLeFQp351SiqS9RQOmKnPq3ZuD8jcEo9V4eATDMvZwtl0F0KpSyoEGoxqxSzuWw@K5TQF/SHbCELnmCLgUaUslI8IXxWnsqiklUMJZuSX5m9V@nsaUoGOlDipbO@c2BPRgR9oMqQW@kz3LV0Rt0CEvUcom0LlHlByNSwXED7IRmb2SHFdGxoFouQFkhuK2VtphBo82QyPmi2q9WD6fhrEJQS3uwUMyU58zadrqU20nXPeEOH9@@ZwCAaEBclEy3@eAN4OhjWJ95k1IRaB5dSUqvNZhfLWpKzOTkHxTQ7l4NtvsG3s/JGUYE6m9MhMIUwyRIfygbNiVv4jTtoLFgG1KFSUWuciCPICXLPndCx9VxZFSpSYasgs/FshoIbByISaUtSLT54RyCZSiZLajK5sKzTyRrOG27wi4kcam/T9Z2pJIhskryrFoo7PCiAfJWvqDyALSQu5pLIYc63yL5meJqLY/4c6r0kD/b6BTe/mG83uKnIHYxMy9SyxDZ1/HaZqZ@KHCqtWdI1B6Sv@diWRW4PSntYFblnYPwZ1NU8wC3lCYtP91PAaO0AYZVOh/jD2dAAi0jkZnR2yBev@0ItEbyHSS1DkK9wz/B1/G31Jf5KLx/vPcXfg90ELsonu1@BsAr4l18@fv70@dMH9JXrxTuRX@bY5YhEV95PxU4tUaPjuDhlDskwNf7Dj12cLiXSBmDKkIwoiA36vvouS6UV7JwibRDyZV8NyGw3XrJ7C180A9Qc3c@6Sdp0ya5hou1OPtVAodwhSahyzR01VTXXbqolUEug62rKDFRVlRrkopOgr0g2gL@nF5Dp7UwD30r/KpnNtIwQFv0uaQwym7I6S5x1@GIlx16hbijyKdlI3t3CT18LJHF2utFQtzLJo2ouk7yfzOUTZ6nWZiOjzJIS2cqosz4uLsJFKlIS4FRj605uK/k8Uy0PslUlg1cVrtUkETYSu53sbrricZSTSWKJwBuVvfre4HgvGGYne/uNsjoL3qZPvOzw5VKQxdYmkEzNvNxdit8AXeglTrZdqTfycxy7uCI5WUsmLpIkkZwn581km0vs0vf@VfbeP0lEb/7jEqFgmjqXL5J0gqSDp1Il4aXSdNo@mCf@SnI3kcTpWOJ574CpaV3Qph2@Rf3VVyoImoTthB7OxMfBWVClCgWcbExIr8be52o59/jwqX3ffWBwidbG5YaDE8mkxjOUPHlnf/I1QsZQY0nSqiem9XwwX6c0GoKyreJ@SSVSBSWgrxQF@bLBpFmDBhRVCHn/iz/IT7fL8KzKCjyraiGjNhrKFqihifH7L37Pd2fk4uDTvUckibN/f/vHP1JLf/vH/4aucU7O6YygmislABKdSrGUuLgYX1yAEjhnYYVEO3FtTVcbyCQpWqW0JQIvSGUNHB0pwUgK6nJJSSc8IRGscC8WhFRKkdT0Vq4spyHkMtiTJqXKZXgMZ@WpF18s8OnEwbFZUJXd7R0o2U4ur9Y2oFqVaDsHEv22Da@S4BLlx68uCYEHvdEbDEyVuiQpaEfvBLL9TtiGO9TwO2GDvKo3cGGagjtBhJO8W/g@Oa64SDYy0laSgK1NGs15bd7O0HliOvzxcstuXSFGawPfSlz22rLhZ2x59GcY9JF6ePAYPhlbrz0@tZWWpF6P9js4Ry8IjQRrdR2DFBrAL1sS5HIrnNhlP0Fopd//4q@ravFv//hXLjuXnc9UVa1UKkVFTfzsZ9sTe@IZvcbPIOJRuPsXMJFu9pBZT5xTw/bEaMyBdnamjZ@aMu1orIKw3dvMIFbkEHWeS0xstMcYfDhygWMUBHRSc2AbPTpiwZ2hRk2rtcP22@qlKNgWAYMkS@05usFPusZxoa3D7DV3oGcpDrKFm80222nugvsIg0A/I2Dz1biPFqjAYwQamaN3PGvijunbnCkaT2lnyV2IAil8hHuZbQB0mgT9tgCSGPrqa1FZlj1KNapzk5HhebgzGqgj3EcQJdiR25qRseZ6BoU0bdAVRASh@aQBvSak3Ya0LRahQ31TtPQMIEtY7lgkG8w47iPQLykVTFA7ibkNADWQKR8BAaAMqQCx2SbbJJcmF2YmU1tsuzYnUOn4XqMW7gvGYTTE1gMyRZFrCAdeYD7iN2CRL4IaBrkX8wyRMBxsyVUdDFCMTp9QoTeBHaYfjApwnQ@xhmjRyN27i1zV62YvTWiJEP@pOcZBW1oP9uq8ArLQkr8DIhVUqkwGK/ujZbYDimdodoHrBLaTXS0WlfD4OOc4@H8w0yJHXqkqGlDDAgT1xVqFDiSDyEh2Voc62a4TRS2lSZR5HfKu00zRXWOi4YnW9I6ofhYGziGHP0uEX1gCYXUSHwgP@Pa@YV2OLiOCewSMsAndR9AfakwYBF@WZ3s6otA79MPYUSwoimlR6L7pgilMV3aF26mlckoaoy22n6P5oO9wqXmCb1IV0nijsRCawF3D7b2CdDao@qo7UKHe2LHpfmA@iiZ8lw04AmQUJPDE8Q2W7Yl9jp9DC@qGRo7nCEoJlg5yPuaY7m9GvyNP4@ISqa5raKchbbLEGIhEH/WIWiEpymg2LhewI3RpGolmuAsWFNK4axkjyNIzw6AvVXtVSRqA4jfp4iy09NgEvho@MKH7sT3pPiOwdG6emtIJ7kssOH1895oiByygK2LzY4uswNicWD1iOc4pscxTg81vpOJ7q@GXGIpZMH6yQNnFCYStotqr5rI4EKZkGRScJbiVmLOcjcXdSM3S1@85ZSPVwRq9pD2YCbViGWeaHaMvPS65YDDFm3kc3UquTtB4SMGzGIlcaJlsV6YkbsuUTItA@14qzdH69SAKxhRx3myc4hN8WvTGlulTJzd2jTOCgyEc9jEgNPVOkAVsxVDaj2gHQNsetCzc3s13q1BzGciJ20vp0PQCAW@TOySncggIKSMoywDgwKqvL2OHMIiK5fD8HlSMSCeLUK5A6xz1IAy3jwrYD@OH3I1uutnegr3JRoAOOx2aVp2wZhE@FGIP2DqQn2nRNyCwCDlckZONFJ8BtBk@zTPUUfyr0Rm3c1SWVMl1TFmCGAJSAxaqKmgocuhep4vvluGajHuaxz5ugVwPTH9@fi7SnQwnrikaHn7Ly3NszZLGAxPUYUfyjdE4@GqyqUvjEO/CJbBP@Inj4XhnikptvXJ3xu4c1/fqwZrJVLLvJbFzPMNPVQ1GZ2hfQYb7HmWoByb9zJ2eCpZwMv5T29mLkP@qyH9COTlHJIQgmml2ltWzgCzb1U@z/fNeLQg4ow0SkEMtGqEn7i/qhg8jL3SZ434E4fgoR6OgrnVK1xUAJp7NGCySZiUMIWfhY/A8NnGptW2ckz3X1WYpGp5GaGTg1IyqPWQG3T4NASdu/H3BNrs0p81Zeyn6NIoOnVq0jgcEeQp7rhuRsp1PMXzKwqcQPmXh00WiYbLNaZupZOg1x@Ig1@Oa8RAS0cxCmDnbJXQRQjGDHk4UhgIhZ0t@uLZUr9PYIb3ZE9RjPWQM4IkxENxISc2XrWarbXvG@VY7Iw2A2XlKCKhxQN1sU5qe9yI3Ut86s8aOt@QF3QdVb4J8o5c@DLiB8QqWMaogyhiMXibu7DgYBWuLmEIQFBgwoB4Ggaga7PkpM12LttqlgcA4TX5BY5axZpCZNtW@gqDAD9QlRnpG2DiidgwR@kdFgmxCCAlbDvtyYygdXrgOwISwAv3YHIjIGUm2k0DJK02FyZoaraRYrgQhzCaQHdXV@tWihOFQFc0rQbFizoP6j2d/40tnvw/tYnXuKcOyDqPGxZsKLhAHFSJoLpSqpFGP1SvkQNrSLMOFnuuA6adBbw3JbEmhmcHSwSJ456avD1OxytfTrH7ou/y8zVcjVpjV61DEWZ01S9YuQpIygkfRvCDaLGSEID4TIIBDXhnNCKJN49Gm9ToTHGS6Jtp5LJNTmskpi8Kgp2sy2Q6igfV0GHYvWD1t0E5x6ToP@BTWjYIaNOaJp50ZuJTj9WQ0RqsqTHMhcygXBDyEKjbymd5emXozlumY0LqCABnxGoIe@wh0lbsq8BQheopkFCNlKKPYU8AGTFYAg1ERXOOYDRQxGbWBQeHnM7QfgLbLZ5ocr9CpAvzJ7OSzoWd4Ktc95WVIZdlTzl75/YN4tpGysQYa0z4UOY8CmVuMVCQ2pInn0o3i2Q675xxH334h95@SFw/3TsjJwwPy4Pn@V8nXnz4nL/aenOALCUfP7z063CdwHjx59v9290VbbSRNmtfUU6Ql3FSZUknCBtuAsAUIW/9g8AC22ws0XUglqG4hqVXCINv0mdmLfYHd@32EfZV5h7nap9iNLyKzKksI7O7@Z/8943OMpKrMyMjIyMyIyIjIBgc2Zf/e0whgHi/4JPW3Is5gv1CpPFEMeaM/GIvPjbvhyfN9ErNfE75YyFeT8OLlufwIetFoTWo1kJkZLjsxZy0mCR8aCemoLQLHQlib3cFw9Kqo7GlIEgQkvQuSRzoxlSUgVDYm1tYeRCTwt0gmJZ1MO@T6ohidh7gY6QxqE1yauriQvo3J0sXqRmBCsVDwPadUgitE7UBpwqX//jAFDxp7b/YVYmE2dnc2mwfN3Z19tbW7Rz/ffmzuvCJ6NvcP9prr7/CKC77Z3WxuNTfq/EAQqAQK0Sm/XJLqeB8KAYozVVq/Qjbk62zTXzlZtOg4vb66CtkxLlFzl/QZj2Jazz9H7bkVh3hJiTMeTyblztb3Xr0/rByr6DfIAEZYYgm98C7hLM@zFbXKrdF0XDvqFWT6c9KmUtXjGXsxVsisTdOXVR3@7isDnNXcdkyrzAa0uN7cSElUCgxCyoCmhh4QbIAyKl1N/dKPe@7cnL/KINeotVa3j6wu0pqY2fQPVH1plLEVhymmtUkAxYlxs4dVrLqSPiC@pwcLutnRUAqox@kDKaCeyINR@GvUhHalFnWJy9HuJQw@akke/HIx2GLBST1NH6yHLFY90zjJuPGQhuo0uz/hYkDqM1xreHPlVOESwIUqCZePoUJ1ZWJEpHYTy5PsJpstW3@oZIHW0w6SimvDkFxWgLfEDdCkw86IVOeaF6gDqM9RD7OHJtRZN@yJkSBTbpn31DPEh9a0323caw0ZT9WW@@iZAdXpWOXxSOttSr129L31qOb6rRZDbUXkrOfGSPMtBNZvIfBnwBCgkr1ehC1OOc@@igDT72hWdpM@cSSMBL/b5Ymd25cw9VkVtF3D/SX@/NnTRPazKnFmyWPsaIg@I8ewbPYkTdMc52WV75nAKtg67w9GsYyhm@8BLZyRXIZBpamPQPDn2lquNdBhssVev2c1ekpcfEerp8SU39Mqc7xIl@nylWXdJ86Pe4lYpoBOeIrrXLMs@b5KaG2L1BlcHsUya98DAEXecbK143eVkJ7zrLa2uX5U@v1n/7hcPpNlQdLnG7Mc/su9AthJ4IciJj2SkUdmpmmgTnJ5itraSqVXS8xyA6xG8yvujNTLk5X0nRjkbz@HX8Lkc3749WtNapWwMum7GpJzN1vdfHVomvS5zrHSSpK1dhKytNa75onPMNP1@iV8EDAKK0SRHtYRWAxytxXQhJAlxPTu9LJDK4sIZma4U/ieWmOdI7vRAw4C9niUf3LXa/NrXjlTuZRFTtcs0b6BXPU8S3Hj/eoWuM37wdH6/f3gnt2LnWwPfwja5r3Q/hBupfm7Ycm2ZMH6frC/3wNWNrc/BZb67t8NWDbJ29BSTk@Z058tpvbm@1v8@dbY8dwjMNh7B/1BBtRq7bLXxYWhJj@aKxU8G0wmEO0fbDb29lSBHceWqS6te/AFa@tlELAfmGuJ2N29x4tdkApN5l8mPJknOZuP@XffZJ5KvDuWCi2D@Joe6WKR3V3TIZWKVz29s7AIwedTvCAayuWx@2LWoORQA745rELxywbN6qAztZtF2XzixD4m0XTzRTa2T7n4DEL2bio6Go5tQLbWHJ7h7HX6@H0Q@XjZtCMCFgLi0OE2SdK035CesI/r26lgEORH8J5hMUOKYygRsIuGdjCNVPIS9l9nKGYkEcJFFraWdS0ca9REPp41Yg6b7LANhLCF6pdi86cXZonnJ6v2gHrZpufmtyASMj2q/dLmCqp@fLOSXl7lZvtkLRXI7bk2y9gcGiyPcWShYa/cXeghTguWJpeHyaZotb23qdLfpynZJXItGZpP7Yx5SZCXFhcffwv2ZC9M9dJfhS17yOT6OboYkH6fgUzGCZ9UEec2d3zzPmOAe0gnh09mwkxUJFFnyp6S6ztvRjZ@hIuYSwgZpBNsnRPciVY9dT2B23TosiPZ0LnIrT5YUzjtqMyaW9S/ub85LMjfbO/BH29PJhsKwbh2g3OrN/1hEmV@K1aQjfUIzsX5Z9Fw2ONicuJ/ASguH/Tf647C/ihiEpZe4SWfutk96ejzezFM@8bWwI0oTjZ@dR6OaJ2zWCrzSrG7utXcbqhHnNWiw9YHc8haGBY8a@15EPfuQ4DXYLZLYPtgL5eHyTL9Jxx8A5LIxP4uLtPG@yZuTBGSmg85h7Q2nOq1tTo5@p2kFfYQjuEXHiaq4P9AFT2wS2N3y3Pyt8Npt9pcfUIuGfRcquUXSkGBq9IzEhTwzMuDkNHEc2vDwlmmObjHATRubA/4mtHoWqxnfJAflqvPKkvPHe5dzx/5F4fPj/1HrVpB0eYb9i6Sy@FV@9ez/vmnjuqqwS@n163x59@UWnyCXFxq4QfJtVRdqpU5N8xThTRdzyvMuRrBF5w3CvdyBcYFck5levjKA8W3CypWmpdxhjjBperRheFCOKGMaheHS8e1Xq2ycnHYO16BG8xovjaar867ePAD7aK0xqCm2zocHWNPta2uUe8TX7PHl9/ow1PFh6f05E04jPvb9Z1XOWscBACYwPRpCMZDDPjODM7RcDob9KIrV5vJfAWOdSAgOTN8bl6Fkymf8sMc044JMxoVn6TZ5Jr/jj1nphJcDkZ9fmNC9cFa6mv81ZkxB/0VuQexHR3GJqCf71ZLrrMyLhWJ5elYzhlKVRHXqvAu8iwQh6jJy2HhqFCA1w0Q1d4Oh8dOEkRh6xxI4Na6r3Kl3uoq32FHrJYEbMVzPZxb85Fi5Rhfu/SVPgbsvoAmWHJP@GDUoe7jdxVf5AnbqEZ8ksxHSA5LiniDAxL1hT0AuP4qEUAIPyMyV6BNnFryIkFSvGvYuICA1rzi/4AWATgeyaDMoLOALe3VMuB8lsI0QrOaTPR8hm8SFFrRP92DUpV/3epGWt6T4kySeXRd/0pASx5SfrWGj25WzbWqlUw1U9gixcw3qQFLF6lHbyKaVmO1EXW7hLTQYiYjB76yB5xufz5tPzlEm8cp8vK@dOt9Kfc@kPeCVFYqoA0@K7RsFyoUv2TlblQhK@bfaqumWHgJaKRbAYkkWdmV@8omwah/EmeF19KhFK5MX6zmXpSsNz9NGX158yBXJ2Xw9P2hvNf8vaBHPsUyV/Zlvn18OnqA8MfsP5NcGvTi7gtH3xen34DNCkRNpaQ6X8GhzKSqaS8lvZyQBAc7P0/btVoGZb5qVhyeM4W11ZeFQAsZL9xJNMTP59bEmjJHLCpxm/NMuGt26aF2@PUDCwTDBKMpM3PXTOWxrjy2wKLUA9Os@AndmuDUtckpXoPn0Ff8MZM9j5wpV5z@ckYwv5bOi/9fnkC86D4oTCdTfjXBgao81J26ZxfJ2h5PQpy@SOxYVuC0zUi8FDswgz9I1wl7oTArxS26p280pbMCVcO@dw0hXt44/6f8yHkVkow96EbXqg41I2Q/BSfnAjqKEtwBfB5xQAqude/i1JEFvit2MtTJ@hYWcdySQbR29sBpdmAs5vI@vmmXTaoUqF1AvoqTyHqRXJ6dwd0CPmL9KyytsLjECGHqjcWgQXPm8YI4YkYKh768AHfjMxsJGTmZPen9sIGj78p1pKudWF9dw/Z0OCMikpO2tGXH@efLuPXrxiuc5z6tVh5XLZJ90sfBleDxk8wFgYhkXiwgdHux@sRxrLPhlpwNlwDQV9vY6N8Tb0afol4vcuq0Y3DBBFcaR8NPUTtwnL0oPQQGXLAyTibhqdi/HLbEuENCV0jMCD@6xJfjMOIwfGJ/luPiFp@V@Q4OrbLTZhrqTzHum069eTt9nA7zgQUcaYUeqHQRjYgojzyVR4nPnjUuLLtcwBBF1EAkgHU2kZKh1x/FLRoZtmQ5XQIlxyBZY732BCbUXqsbwn0umIYANWRRwCBgjpLuw8HRh@Z/CAelO2bO2EMzMmVa/fo8V2i6R8OYVt@MwDwqXM3CnQb44HVzX@3vbh18qO81FH1/u7f7vrnZ2FTrH/mMGwflnG1Fvd7dptUlPU2XU/NdelCo71PNAr9w6jsfVePHt3uN/X21u6eab95uNwkagd@r7xw0G/u@au5sbL/b5NN3gqB2dg/UdvNN84CKHez63Kqp5mT11O6WetPY23hNP@vrze3mwUducat5sIPGcKpfV2/rewfNjXfb9T319t3e2939hkLHnM3m/sZ2vfmmsRlQ@9Smarxv7Byo/df17e2Jju5@2GnsKXYSsHq53iAs6@ukwqIl7udmc6@xcYAOZd82iHiE4Lav9t82Npr40vixQd2p7330NdD9xj@/o0L0Um3W39RfUecc9xtUoXHZeLfXQHQRKLH/bn3/oHnw7qChXu3ubjKt9xt775sbjf0V5Wzv7jPB3u03fGrjoM5NEwyiFr2n7@vv9ptMt@bOAe0Z797C38GjQf7QwHXgG3WquskEhhsEektE2t37CKigAw@Arz68btDzPdCUqVUHFeBRsXFgF6MGiYgHdjfVTuPVdvNVY2ejgde7APOhud/waMCa@yjQhEPGR2IdavQd9xrjRHjJV2JWx3Cuz8Opmluqvvm@Ccx1aeKA/abmFibbxmtN8wBJUywjStyHzSC8sA0rnduPPkUI9L9tkZluo0ljijZ2Nxu0I@tYsEL24h3tOs8mgo3sd7TTpC/pZy6oox2dXp6d4C52eGGl1cTwcZGc@Uis7CGl65FzT/yhtq9whWLx5OR9/YQU3f2TE8//npo5NL5VQ5vB7yvl6T4iax80bxh@lpeF7qs5Qq39oA86fSXJZbikUP8H3lzhUeSpcrkd6WpwbwVgYzpK5NjkHEcptDSyZz2S0GZNsmWCf8eaHbiia8AHrRPYSannUqif0J/e1@yHbA7WA1qdxdxVLkOJZTTiz5FpRhphp2H@o3124w43GSRR9OuZW7Gbg84fnPX7bWS90HW47Ij0wDPX@0b10@hsonppsj4jy8fOOv1cYvRuFmHS82dNMqXHJRhyz1z8ORnxh2ewEa9oWE25KTZWa6Ol@4NUh0eSr7Tz942jMwhB5ntT/7H5AdpcZeHJysTz1@lzmVtIBIGcIbThHXK9Y/54fSwFaIKxtzqRJNY@5OWyVcf4m6SFr6jgOQpdxW14/tBefR7xvk4kIUH2MuzabWI3HsbXNva0Dr/aq79Zf7e1RUsnsH3ybPHp0oqTBqb96MvnR7TDWTs4Lm9A@zjJafzKmiUbJPjwTLFSLGXszwxcLqMgsnSZQeOH8IRO/TbynkxYyNDdBBmZe3DRK0SgQ0Gxi/oDx/Dr1JmpGcDNddVDby7CaxbxQ5KVmAe0M0t3zKN2jT@AnU5/M8XTDmkG0izGeUyIc0m74HWvgErszcLKDYe2oEhQMHwsgY4pDdjUVV3WoWH8S/O2NYqJuDJivvKwc01C4sEkFsr4VfRkZr9lT3xtAOb4Onryo@Y3@vpRh4ByQGiYjOqjfSLjVloTdurMGK07faghHyNrIsIOTUurClZ@TyPFc0@bk1PXeWs2MCrIHAqP4zzgldTTfrJJKJ1zL@c89UU4Fe7tgLOiOVb/Js6d1h0NZcV42Ovfxm9bCaw0DECodpW24ZgiH1NPb0POHJn@Ej0Y/j@QJlPgr5LGSdAzallhst9FSYYqtCL1lYkSX5mDBut0I6Om/ehjBubGHpjztGP69Oaaw0NBAj06Y/PgIwcGd9wpBACTw7Bhz9/UJe08JNXpZcHT1XFO0mtdDFyl9wqzVdyCW1o69lns8s3ZCn54yhNbk9XgNlVVL0VxO@VZTyrThCqvHiYFAecZD/nyIzaApBOeufRcvFYnOauiZ5lZB3QwkrXhtNOYIhJLb@48tXukrCDy3NqvT74MoQj0GvC53U9OH9lX4p6bj0mWu4MPOE4UGZmgJmPz0UGdp@yI2Y0A52GbjSHIMDm6wgbRFegczJpBU@5DdhRBI5nXYRaJi@XWC4i0vK1epdizZRIcmmL/rid5wyKxapkSgcQNawx78DMknhkMol6g3oRjQrn7fd0WFis/2u/78F1EY2KW0PWRTbPV7w9JdAzRb8LRj8deoD5oo0PUSy6HOsKX9rN4qC0SRuinZiA2ifbO24zk42LUkpjkBviyMH9wly4ieIgyuPi6tKRcYl7Do2vG6Bhfz1eVu5q9WSWacOA@E3FVLeGeEy4lBNVB9RFTME5S5YJ9NrkdnDuk0@@qP/wVez9EoF47aqex@xZItgXKIDV7HAXdGknXB/2ELRo0FLCApJSoiiEtdVSlPfqpZift11TI4scR3c89@ePtpExqvKWooYxxdevEfEslGkxQaUEHz6fh9NWFRUZlmsJ1c6cyxvH0@WNrVTjqpUvKsggRtYdGdMQ3WTfTbx/xTRv5aw8TzB56gjNuLYICYcisOFe9vc4xfvAp@BBHw7ZtEyVJph0OYH5j1affY140pkMdGNsKR0k0Jg2gVY6vywzjxP1b/7x3stHvhmdxPw5JT0PKrGtZ8fB1zF8xYGfD/lXCiWLlHgOrUHucfecTax2oiN/pueSKFbyWjKKBa7spjIbjOlKJQ4vh0Ewcoqb7FfP3YDKKMK3zZDGrlDmoAI@A/fGq3sqddR9Xp1WWE30A0Avc2oQHBYc@RshjUTMt9QfuhGcfCpzeV8DC8VSVVOjd4bGXw/g5kYiPYXIYG2RuuSXYnYBmdifGh@1rv81RusP@iNatzQi5SBOXH/sh7tCiVeQFPAWWVfVZxaoqpyjXiNTFl/Hd5F54@g/GnhD4C@hXH0/jlmmMwEtcR88GWpNZmdBx@IQLuwfGvEbzSkyrWHxGu1A3B/TkehJq/vX4Lmqw5w8JRToQ9RZXYka6pPggn7l7QkvOydjDpjKn5jwO/oQIUh@5lbsZNvqW/yxPfhziiuUMC9OGhuxaSN9FqhZRCbfyTLjX2ihL1pFvz5iFhe8dtQkC1qa5nFnXVbkFI7lwBEos@yuOtfpDWowLE9TTrh5zyag/mPtO6t25dkyNXZxG65bnfdMRWJitRpvlozaTtjbG1/GKM4nPBNPkKcaeZsRDUF/5e8rmk0S8rp1gvtVOxt@gw100y/ym0k0lHe@2zH1sip/g0Ws2mnRKMe4I419Jnx@eUMdP7l5BNExRr054xTjBknEylq8WqAkypVT6fgox92ncJ@jRJsqh3TbRzh6fO4k66SRnkgKYV7kwcNATqY0QtEnr0qAD5wvXM@dT6SKVCpzX/piP8qqlU6ThwAsBCKk4KmV2KLHgZoM1wUecP6vjnsBbqIqViL6t2R4OaVqslGCct0obd7THw8m4VD1eEUjXKSTSKrjUfZD0IxQ7PLlmKLdIQVN8CinSHt1am86/v1d/tS9UjiBIbX6tPX0rPjrjqXnChv7Yr06uIQNnTemauRmVnwgnvDTQXCAt5awbiboK6S8eCsfDu0FPI1Ig5LGLj3ldAwlvlioptVHluj1GEU@TW2abhytquErGUPIb5NdTUURdVlwJQCQYU/1alSAg8J@xx6FAN@qMcpyXQ1SPEVWsVTEt6SHnDcj8PKe8B1F1gSeLVonKtBLPbRilqUBIsJheJkOEZJbpRTIotNFNxcUq8XR6f7ISJBAb3heK01DoUcnTMB05ISDfRFTxshXlsKr8iuZgfvlk0cu9TPmb3z6vWG8rk2@JPimGh6Xq5NtnldzbXLMLC/mquZpED89uNfeSSOHZCKerwl/7x6EpdlKg1CfUUjJyUob2z8ZNUaRlkt4W/JKoVQ7KNjKGgWdHhhv160SSEObSFt2fokjN8ZEBshv95d4az1SDic6mNXfU4@RJYtwVhZAl1gK2enQLmi57U8BwYhIUGJ2231HvD7a2bCUY0cPa0egiGi5WKhUw8amdHsr4VsOUFPfL@dLlzmW3Wx5c/W34/rTMaz@urewm/WWjQUc0JDQpkqA/PJPcacCBiqJ0SQeyQte/7HTsJGU4ocTg0bBJSZ0NQfEGFKdOL@8PJGnyVrbB/owOon8/q3T2XYUiaGoo5hiKasMl@FPBnJ4RefCgA//s9KSKgWFhNt5MtG95tbUv2EGQ@48HixN8eF8y9@TC66jb7fvqA66aQaaAmZvJCltbdoWKFMEJI0f3XiI9dkIyWfQp7lpxxShi8zrAmY3JZGIzmZOQPWovOmtcD9zC4U8F2laoy/Po5jwyuPiqcFbwdDql7wArfEhof1fpi3DgtphOk4Vpq9czOPtGGD2u@lN1n1wRj21immbfLg2iTkc34GQN1HWPZQGT7YmHl3tyR/GUuIWj62oHNKwIDI0TMXD3@2og1Owftyx@GnU637cqcqIsGdg/tCJKrsC/tiDyGQDPQD39iJ7ImPlPJZrWWxMJRUTAQTq72@sOKpygguM8bNV@u3Lr9bqaHczPq3p9nb7g8ob1utrEg/V1tYnM@Pj9Q21hcXFF1txN7ws9XDcPb9Q6wWAL53zrfLhJP@ldDXFj8NbGEM@Wa7P@yuxJbXVtJSkf1tcR1k/f/v1f/9u//9f/Xq7rH/8TP9b5x@FPaaEgCMqzrS@zP9ys4Pfh5vHc7Onh7OB47mwFXEZkqF@O@s1RKczcR4PhqVOUXcB6yn6kRs/m7DO6qjIpry/C4a@0uiyrYispF/XTRHKr8hpbbEXW8whxlKekwpu0XJOqvIO0xxfhGOZ4Gp1WBAc82m@IkoQL/EClvpytGMM90sGkBdJTlaLOxMMy66cIMS1ZJgXE4tKOVYp7SdSDBfwTy7zSPccJ6TMenWj@Lf@kL19@dOSqRxX1yFePCgX@wEXMj4682XKM6Fwpll7RnB0twM1QJTELeqw/cDbKCXI7ziwntQQkk6aCC0sUnJ9qfxwsIymJkzNnBrcTKDGR8CETqhS/zPZuaFi@UImbQi7UhgWFE63FcGPWiUo6vhCBwkQcAbKWL4Qgy31qEid9HJGMb2XzRI@1w/k2GTDIuvdqi@c9HtBeNNvTPs85XQqJQNl9Xp5ib1yRYGhGG2@k/QwBPlARdbLCkYRzxTlHvLytXnI3JQrb7p9mPvF1GEcj45sulX5XFhOIN7dNuNmejmvRjtxyvKIKcXq8YjVVmPT9Vo5V5eKyO4oHOlyBW8eE@pK2diMzCSPKgASOZMVdvj3D2FBgMkVNDIukkx2rdh9dl5mg79HDdPACOTmyiFD@yaW5/XVibntljhIx7CA8wEilrnydMO4mOuuKXMh3Fg5PkT@b791U8UjOzdieh7sSJjDud1KkA4bMLufZfKauFAfD8Owi9FVxp38wDMdN2rZI8hm1Ao96iBRMQAKTTzc9rXsGYemRHhKmSNoV9hxCRt7uWCcQlrEtpDEnGFIzFXTaFUyCHDsxJaOvubGaoGPG1X9gEGyUby3e6WmkXmJ55YWnkYZUsMNmeJrdmjqOacGeO@nEKTiCajozDS/oSpfYaC/44JdW8i5yBOi2CzoKUIciLD1H@9idzqJemNucBl3HBPqXV5Tsi5jPnKxdvJEcDeVpNcsJDaxIjvwpnwVC9iaTzsiZcd2Zo0QnPC7a@wiE5yD1xS@HKk5TNHOKX44MUe96sSyWEztULLQnJgxUkz3/CUKnG54RfuOrcAxWPCq6Lx6UvcOfjnrHj9yj3tejzx5jopdks8uWVFEfZpsVS88V2hnLfu6n8UpLiAScwOmoly9w1FMSw2KRgBApu4c/lY@/lgmho6LnPSofFYUguSEDJuX72ysDfPkWmsU8FuWiM@M98szguy@qnqK9lT8xhvLAk0/CwiiVbKYnPWfYIVAcp8s3PEOxKz9bqDxZqD4hTegsui4No0vst6Xk8jS6JlEigTpLW8/R5xw35Ahxc52EK/TwmvoZn/VwxyePaKKDlPQSqqc5t@OkbEV1AuEJKk9UdkEChLh4aZkQh49Q@H1FLGfKci4ocR20uM/F/pn0L9BOmGBdm4wOEY6El4H4iLAJtQTImvHu5FDPTJc5jnMK1MZ5RIMMIDS85aK1W/T6vZIW1rxgbgVCNKJmurivcXKO3pqiuRk6q4WpuQequvbi6b/9j93fiqPi2kL5w5A@R8XfikvPivKVvtCvx@bXp@JacRXFlm6K4zLpwPT16b/9L6q/9jeCgzfjVfqztmhgLY2La6UaV/laXFuiL9WFBWr3f//Lv1AfZkVjw20Fsye@YsRWDEU2wh7zLr1XTfRS1NK5bFnhwCzAEA9D0s3pBxyjrheeVdhMV9ReFZ8infnK@KPoLZ4ds0bsKiSWDONPQZKRVKihgZKANC4UHWX5bhi3DTBvhqb6@WGwlJAG8LN250ibTF03HiZwGZoVtYgG0JUWSZ@XL2uVF4XUvWO5YHxKVowICdVOr7XPHq8QO7ztR6O4lfeSMNP1ohVeRacB@DCI2pekU/WSbv@XYfkTseRFdeFZuQPjfpn9uMsDhlQajIPPJAjqDPOkGLLTqa@GNAL9C6Tw8jnvPAn0W@mZlMm4TlL2IGqJDSt/awcVkRg/X46H0Z0gE6Vd/ksCPHLL61TpVjbhox7V3N1bVoX5tKCUY53XAzZv2TlWp8AoiTcs30pIAgz3AdZB05@gPjzjICSuNSQIUiQI2@2TUL9znZmCSSbsOzPnUXdQK7BvGPVmeMmuxZr@ImbeCaUUw4JQKvFCB1gX0SgkFb1W4CfQx7MWkCZFn7WmqeIysnZ0Wa3Vt2tbHKx6d9NX0vQVjSikhKydlGesbGzKLiZrSw2mymF0giO1qQ1Ta4m51mQY8AcwSGRYmh2EJejucAQkUS3rjvYqs4fNZ12YeOQqkpg9MS3K3S5OMQt@9E0JiaCG7IR2A2mMFoidfi9ahocy/d6XCIiaScQf9xzJ5zfx2uT30GC4D7uDqJdLWyfJR2Vb6tF@yAIHYikVkUDnlbV9sB3ZPVLQaYqt9JKGAgwvBQ8s1VlmZYsLmuFY5otSTEqoQkHsVIctlV7A0NH3O3AKBTwoVKoLj58sLj199hx5gGd0b6eDQaUAWsDgPCQYLFG7pGTjea1WmCvII1zScrtJQJ8GFgdwcOu68hgr@fqgVq1oYJUCw7riy0akujZXMsgM4jAKsCOQjuIOC677YvkQHTs@antf6T/xt8kPyAxn0tGGQnprHN5mmamcC0k4UOOFmZPiuLgrmbYQeWOXjfqdPWSbiODrKmxPDW0jA8TofNi/PDu3uSPQqa0OaMIQwUfD8TJrUK@iUZZgzMIKsqg2ODSt6IuagXd4uwdwysWWAJlPgNM003krQ@1pitkxR5sQMmsiYhVHiJbrqM3OzJ29vmrsbE4ipm@34fytAjewPVtJuONMZkggg9ssrO4eEHV1tgsOJdVrkp/LqswLXAXlqhwOHyJWuoWrWiyqmLWa5YaRex9ZqsyLWWrTrCqNI/CaArNa@TYpTVyr6QUIYhZCbU1KFzE/Pc@xSZbhZA8y5il4ubBs@Yi@iZOEE8zpxgqe9ijlQjSQiZxKTAMIu02lIB2pLGNE@WuDryaR0Ua6c4mKhmlAuyGnmmo0tWTc0aYCjhqXbPEpLdD/5s6GrzYb9Gfrw6YPQXm9/k/od3oJyt34VjW@1WXV3DJDYGeLZZ9b@Ez9hhAlYpaKThibIYjFlw0bqJdmDWg0tzTtZVIf5ub2ccYVYNdQC@HGOqonCRK9sA1kRivvaSoODtfhZ8tivLq90qQpVfS0EBPX/RPboslM1moKSUj5HSAWJkGkiVoybp/JGF480FnyDrXuYhi7uTWdp3MsKwoVie1bZSJ7nmfvpMx9bLGg2WJhGeN4H18w397LG6dRp69j0VLm@AZvPPhzvFH6fuYo/adgjsY/hjsea@54vIy1R7gjTRvOEZ18UVF/CsecjnkPPmnHZzHsQx3rJzpR8S0AvOABQ8SQ0stqBX27YzlR7vQX85P7EZyEFhaXnD/Z@Se680@Wseby183o/9fOl/7OnV/UnV9cxl4zZeS1aGelW//79DgTCd38g6nDC3FXinl/tqdLuqdLy9hNpwzz//Oelv6DevpU9/TpMjImyIGDpK@/n5tFEqnvbzSbmbtFYG6VdHHT03Su9KB7tWsFUh463cvkvAZpXf1p/J9p/J9hNeJveyBraMUop7q8qKcSLC@SJVs5FIKspCfSX5MZ3eqv3rAyfURvULJIs2FrqBUVEsh9eZmdNgWZ/Jitvunm8704y9rO@Q8l4aqlQItGWPWyKS6SLxc2l@rNCCMjB7LaONjbnv8vQoaL8FcdhUbIY2ivom7X7CS2CnaQZp3SnbG6A9j7WufIsYomJyM70tHeKbvM3L2qcWKLiX1xupIgR21yBSayRNo3C7DJiGgT6PpGq4JrrlEv5An1XQpN77Lu8Z/i0ueaS58vqz2tGNxFqlAb/DQvZnrawuLifXuA1ArwgQlY8an8PbPq/wI)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/2dknz)

This answer is for [drsam94's SPL interpreter](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl), it doesn't work in the official SPL interpreter installed on TIO.

Before main SPL code dots and commas trigger errors, they are fixed by inserting `Name,`.
[Available names sorted by length](https://tio.run/##VVRNcyQ1DL37V5g9QRWbgiuwUJPvXWYqTSaEA3BQu5VuE7fV64@QXsJvD0/dmWxxsZ4lW7afnpxqOz8/T7Vku7m@OD9KTN1RnoIvX775I7756mik6R/7lJ9sXt2/v/32T/vvUZZU4KevbftkO/vO0lHg2JfBvrXtC/zedl@8@8b@hPh3luwP7360LbbW6D8@P2/c4EPgbDadRK8meYpkNtyzRJjRB49pTyOPUT198tMEz1/0aDaBHyl2nIAkZjGb2CUZyQ0M2HNQT/HihpoV4Qh4UhkqdtQiYXYIHFMoA32iBBQ/VjHHTCV5xwCRO@/uFTxIwOZj3M6ROU7UkmYGqgU5TmiqgQtszrhRogV5jQzJ5yLTwMnuw2xOkDiJOQlUO3@wui6wTDgXOyV1rK8GiAAaTIxsHVzz2HIKPrI55ZFxTURPOXc8Cmg79RLnT7DiiiR7QktYeuxJM0C0H2SIC2gYVCmi0JJXX3KExRXvi@asZ@w8W9k/y44CpucUcqG7O3POyiVM6nzEc805rqxD8bFNyHKeQJPHNiBPaT11hVuqiSPIveBUUu0AJHLywVzSqBResqPCavAEGKhoHQkmjX41KCXWQAooYoFLEmk53o/SY/37TC2HQEYPtnJnL6jG8jrbahFzgW4@VH2gjjhZTc1gjTPE8LOPvb3kCOIWuLxhQVs@hK@9GwhP31I324MGlsmOXMtleJ10FbytE4mF@spmyzHKIwxqUMRsq1ukrxaz2Q2StOTbOa8aP6Q8ZNtRcBJG2LVnYO/tovLZ7Di5qoTsPEqBLDuIUEVkl1K9zq4eUEPw/9nTUI/Z4Y47mTKZK@gH9b5yhR5A12o/M3UV/OKGxpXNqxRwpMBmH2EK3OjEJXGjl0nQUqPtE9WL9jANBOD0G2h8dINpBO2s0m1knHgF0BaZBi8ddYSAXmrTJMmTdhRAUdE2tV16pqlo3F8qc7RnaBho6Zp7SPtaWq/jyIIxE2Kd2XMLQYBGsx8It/0bdg6CDHsoT9nfo/8j0u4LTwPh5jcDeXBzM7DdtK0UFdZvnMvo4yKtJTAJXu8I91ymyQ2tz4NMuvgEFHBq60vwtN6zunce9P3Pc8tRfyN1XQySi6KsT73BR4Ya33i0A8ZCERzBaiiJ1569mVt8b@bXMOcMfm8Jzyn6fSApwrfK5PKR3XoJ9B8), obtained from [character.wordlist](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl/blob/master/include/character.wordlist). Interpreter recognizes only
the last word in the name, instead of `Doctor Caius` just `Caius` can be used.
Dot on the first line doesn't trigger error because it is part of the title.

Main code:

```
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.                  // Ford = 2*2*1
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.                       // print Ford
you cat.openthyheart.               // Ford = 1; print Ford
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.   // Ford = Ford + 2*1; print Ford
```

After main SPL code colons trigger errors, they are fixed by `Ford:`. Adjacent punctuation marks
hang the interpreter, so `..`  `.x.`. The code works without `[Exeunt]` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

## 414. [Minimal-2D](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minimal-2D) with Stack ([Minimum](https://github.com/Codesmith512/Minimum)), 17960 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405



















































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000';d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlpstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let r,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?/<p>3r=0+@#posHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyckCa^ x._,
 ; ;:
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({a3e12be8-20b6-4e98-a33b-3622a7278f17}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKpIisSTb1KkpFKpbul2PdQq1a3rS7JYIAiSKIEACwAlsiRWdPfs9rrHnllPT9vRbnt8u3vWs@31RIx3Ymfd3rFnIuz9OOGYT/4B5cfGhmPD/Q96z8kEQFAipbpte8OxIAEkMk@ezDx58uQ5mYlEV/OGP/tZAg9y5FizgeX4xDc8n/Rc88xwRXJvRnY10yuoOY5DqD13MBkZtu9VuQRRCLE0ezDRBgbpm5ZvuFniGQbpGpZzDuEqIdsTe@IZvQY85QixjXNyaOtmDzAQ3zk1bPOt4UJYnpD7hnU5uvSJ7oxGmt3zyNg1bZ@GFgg50uChP9FPidb1fFfTfdOxIai4lESJQHT9lMLRyGPXYCjKhDx2XM8ArI5ueJ6DnhXw1FzTebT35OMr8IpMPtYgI2PLmF5JUlHIC9Nwe1djqOTTkwcPrvrmyFcFxyYPrmdJyZO9ie8c@lfxF8jewLA1oooVUb0aWAQC@oZVlsvy1aAS1KHhm/pSOhDwwHShRrWg5oiu2VBDWH9bxBiN/RkRWJ1rlhXVp0c0j0y8iWZROHsy6hpuCOj5muub9oCcm/6Q@EPTi@JRaG@s6YbQMyxzZPpGj1gmRHL6ARZAbffIqTE7d1yo5gCnY1sziGjoZt/EKGE@ACEeKX9oMDwjbQaVbPvAEEQjHmTDMkJsaS4B8PeN7mRAnIk/nvgE8tYzPa1rAdLujPSMvjax/CzpQhgQmfqfDw07YGBAJwKKE4fl6vWEZs1Y8LnW6xEZeBfycWoQE6hGs1UluRz4E8cFqgFUmKMAGeVlVkZjCnUGVdR3qqQgyxB@EPlgbjXLc4LMLGcNA21on7TOEO@R6wxcbQTU6BmUpp8eHhFPd1x4ghNhWRu6CY2u@WR7myQPntxPkkZULaLb5aIqqpMLqIJEGEjONGsCHBKvCQfqx41ic1hlyY1klSSBLKpM8nmSh6ZaJmoBiKTIFXBAm1dzCpxFopZJXoEWVCA5tZTMYlp9VxuYlsEwDRBTCZkfQFS4ynmSU8okV8wx6IFj9RmoThMtkVyZFEukVCAluFZIRYVUMYk8USoFOItwAsYKZAkQqTnIoKwyZIs2ADyLfLdP@trItGZBCjQJnRQUUgKskHcFsKtlwAL3XA7PHJxlxLZ8xHH7Q6D8UDsD9IJlnqJkMiLhhNUpwU3a2pKoRESRy5L3hpg8kBEIWCiTEiRfBIrkIQtAZbUMyRdkVhBvaFhWEG3oYTSa25IMJ@S8BLQoQ03IQFMZiVqCE55B9qkg5FSQaCoIKRUEi6qCO4dJAFwRwopQrcU8S2aoeaeQEEtH7dEKAIkOaBSkOAo0BYkEGKDWCJAaqjwPTJFDpijkCOQf8lIqEpBpZYWU86RcIkDPikygfhTIF3KMArJUgfwoiAz4QAFGUCBPClBbAaRKrkC4GLGVHIZD3BzEBdIoeYiTBzdUnFLEE@IBdyiQpAJpqmplwZCQN7UA5S3kKKeqRajdEoQB3VTIqwospUJu1TKEY9wy0LCMjAzsywihIR2gVpD1gReBGAXID8ULsOBWSwHzatZ4qHVRcrOY3T5GLWKTKCIZIaqMxYN7HqkJWZEBDbYGyL4KHJCjLQfu@Sh5SwEkTURv9EwqrC0T5JgSUaiUpQz5Whv7C7IpRZqj8cwfRn4q83NAiJogCI2Bps@iQGiF2Shw4VvMoa9K5e4CkZxHXw@krDPxrAWSyJFXaVLGmWkt/MrUr2dovb7pDd8t8pqniXQNzbfN00UqhUI2RlQtFlDEgCWvUi4O65sCdF2DIboWZVFLCDN2ogpayrKi0Ox1jf7EHhhCpRzLHw3xJ64PncwizQrzds3BAPrnBR4lS4tJO82Fd4Hm0MrlfC7yROpimq4JXfldog9BuYgCKwx/pbLAkVMRx0zrYg8vgBYGPUIF@7C@OSXduzrtQRYZzFE66UNzHAJX1wLHKpcmMi0XY7xBKfe2LEfiGY@2@Nox7VSSJNPcnIN@h2mW8V4bOrcX2GNhH4ysC32sQzWIhfhM2WEvmQaiLXf40ANbIEahUnQNe2Psmwzat4Z4TF8kkAiohIZzhmor7SCXkvFoJ9p1UUsFjadnuC5BWFBtvSztbr1J1zPeTFCnWuSrD/23Ad18XzOtKAO0H9F8qgzAPelBerPlbPddZ0Q7mxF2p5bjjNeoLtB5nyOih865scj6om/XxmMLNCjwN5gCB5k516i@TZXzeKosQxAJ40GFA0KaFGgepmvolPZB0SF2DnSU5SxWidq4m0Ms92KqVQ4aC6gdHsaxJ5ZVBZ3H0EmuIfWMMwl9mPq1rHZhHkKFDNSqAEVXA70Zc05zEWG6q4pU1TsJa9ZzRstFY/3rYVT0oYlKknWuzaD2@tC1GlNtBNo9QRUaWi4ZAcewGsSaAIMCi3VIeo6d9CMs5y4otFDoqCRUaUaa@ObIAOvHgShY43maaezdac66M2BlSq28SM0dlpMrhBK5q4RiHvmYB2ssoPr1JjpSDdM2bcpBoC55qO@7ICqZH@e7pNXS4HRBtxsHFp6IDgR8hlmLGQsea@2BFq5TjKivGrYHJoYnEhPtL@D8gdMHZjs3oewgsCDqArdOiYAkiLymoi5ylOTIQKNTi5hEH48J@EOnBOz5QC6DOuq8NslbCLSGYE7oE9edkekYasIcAZSvO/0@cO9bYzwEFGTUI/pMh@YJlUy5xxva2pjrOVTM6OPlwi6eNg2AsdFM2T/6RTIwgPigwvbRgETGXxRjPKYFoQTRbKbe2hrQCwuij2eUOFxiEaPvOCL69xzDoyzjuKeRAMDEPGNAGwi0tv5CJI1QXQdetamZ0QP5EzQyxI8JcisLg0kFvPCxYUMD0oE3oelDJWLN7pE@mNoxRRYtD03XjbEfcItDhZppxyyApw/QAqC@QoBM9Ibc5i7ZvsI7ABrxT0yjRYsIsz4ODBMNJW5gzwtU/YiMUCZfrNm15AHi7Erq/CuEWcrBK35NHsa0YaA5REXFxEeBgjLS1IcoEX2UOVTrhjbnTq4XH/ziybsjIvSjtDE3CggfTpQiL8zHehwCnNZ1ROLYQlyNJQ8EXfK4BbXmjVZgdqJMWr24ryhpIojG25COHNtZgRWIGeFFkOUQWheUGZ@h7NCsiBlpc/GW6gjF9mKICbsz6EnHY8eFlsFEz4yOLdAqi3FXYJKnoh4jLZJ7yx0sdBxJ7PZ97AshwtjSgBewiWFLBftKA3kBooyZzCD5HJZiLMO01VNcQf7OaQfAmAl6VNs20ETT3BlDAsWDThoSmhHTdUEYnmFXwXqisEsRKZ9Cz6D1eihfkRy03V9NXESO3p90zelVu1xHT/G1x51pLumjSe6C6gGNKJXse8l0jfrTmLEgXnLGvkSjsisPgBRIhCpP9cHKh67iAQiaZzNbT/FLTYzPEn7i98t8GhwYkWlq5BMwGK7mDo0IZJrRKbRr@lQjA@jEBQGuAvrRnGCAJGKA5oK2AY0QbM1KpdfVyCVID5cI031mkISGiSLmo7QMuxelFRAC8xIvr8iS8FydOoRY34YlQHBactpJLBHwAylBI/LgIUlBD4seVOdjYVS7YZ4Tm47MkRRTSNLkIlKBoQNI0cyYoIKYuul3AqXl7t1Qfdmo14HZQKcCsdlLx@3acAhTBEkNwCLVSYJERN955mPbSKWhvAg8Z7kB5Qk4td4gF/7QhRZHn@ccAAFZORs5OSRsUM9PzNNJ72pF2@iJQDy2OlCdTN3naxyoAKw11G@ianKJqmD7JpGqyLwYn6K@xrzUFyuUD8Bcw0MluB5kJVbDKcxBwKsrScSiBn4Lht6f6VagEjAXNHYmjbqQ/dNgaCsSRNlAJwgb7bWWypBgc2B4yNHeycN60BZZoNQ17eqSh@XomkW9NxGcD@M@Orx3vHf8i50VOCyzW73qIZn5chG72slUGNgTKS@q1c04jgXi@52bcWPEZRieC4KJ4ExjqtJMh85lGpLz6fFXr5IENCEkB00B3HheUWkYDChdXFfzhlc6YTLIZCDJKEoIS4RDEuKMHJh1DNfC/BxN3r7FyruaqXHgjzmzJhpDEHpKh3YYT8TAKwpYGNTtsx6RxgVd1LRx6mHhikOG@fkYdeermaEKdYxlPn764OC4TtEGo2sCBZE8H3Qpze2JwPPWBAzxVTAg/sClk4y4yDhq1TSvKwms60sEXtQtWYMfEKDFIzpEsEZh0bwh5H3/atmor6BHHECfKYaremVcH9K/bEZj@cAuTkfDd1UvSgMWnVXktbLHikKXuy29UDBK@Uq829IXafbiSOk0AfQDod7oQtCpJ6CPuNAiA7U6yP6zR9cy7lElEkwBIcyZZxGRpuVZHFovgkmSnrQPdppjGeILKvF4wqclKRnOFIi6R03QGPzB1PRTcprdlTTAQup7e4fq/RA4GLim4xnUaECLHHsmt4@zfLoHPGI7ljNwyBbEYdphmCCoTWuLuTdw7Gs1pKEnFjWBE4Ugf3H4RhtDX2O@peYjjRU3WtmUo2Z75yCllWIOiUQpRFFJFF58rZ1pQK5FuZ8dfn4AnYhSkOXILdMDSBCLQ8mFLj3mSz2IAAmJQX5WFjCaQLzW2sMAITaDh4UOBF0UcW8RvNKTSkxRWgm/MkufONco/tqZXWEt8GGsBY4YyQ6fHD06fHLweO@zlq8WCkvPeblSBMJBel3QhcQhoxu21i3WNLFYiC4BbcPF5gVSYAIGSjh/NPFcENwigogsA2u4hk29pj5xhnbSS18tzDmGCq9tnbHQY2x8DDSICIZ2z0JjxGVz1tifI/8MfX/sVSUJWvlw0hXBaJVe646lDSQaDzoGy5IUNF0On@LohrcqBmTGmxksBhviAtVhRscRNWvkgPFCZ75RNJAUQ0/HrixzMARbGKfHDTctRhxMSyP1wEIAW1mKykYFMH0C2gb3sJ54xtofKWqZ8bUiq3mJD8GWmj/AbvQNMJ1S0FsBKdJXHknrbusumYGURkxXkSSIuEUHOTyCfYFFQJGkY6do54fEodICR01RVlAavZngmC5IKakg50tKsSCBWQZmGuisAo68CSPN14eC7wiAT3D6dNwgxoV9T9fsvrgVOMLMgt53B4qaa75stew2KOituzRvOBPdnLWbSjtdI9ejbAXw6Rpw71LxkHdDD@Bd6gTWpHeyRp71tOvirKfR1tUjkj8aB32OMCaP90CReuuAvO4Z8baHEaR4oLS1BCsh8DtpxYCQhVE5vCClJGhQ0NMC60mYLwGUXlQPgXNAbsUikMVoRqQwzfwhyI8cSe1TV/q6hoveuUBqLGcFh4bF8QxEHgVCoS3kMENhAE1wzDBgVpJgAqHGg@FJlgW20CQmytDux6ZnOkmPTtagaoXDtt4Y6pGOeuvYUXg4UOlDBx01PuwogL@wnyDnRhIH9DWPDZtCpGDhQRgfzMUIA50eiIbG7WipBfAhjUVHCEB4AWvj@O1wMdyJ4w7A7JAgzROOf4ASY9NpjAEUEiKzguyxgrCUqM9ykU5t59xGbF2DlIWu6bNZB2fi4gS82YuXDcBzKoMBbLRwsa6FztR3DZ0N97LItBRgh2pkZIwcHM0ABY9KI4MWQWOz/GiOejh0Di1bFnDqEvALZHcfBKlusCErYYR2HHD1AUn6rrQnfC5pwltoUDeod1j4WBUHlX4SEmB5zQUdqAkGYamC5Iwo0As65IOB90KNO2At5Cxeqztjw75qdjKjNJWu0bURySSbjbpIbmxsJKvJRjILrh1wbaNrB10ZcO1Ql0BdCCeii8bIUheGNmkM9Gsn580Q8zTdRh6YovLy1hyntGa1mmtntaYS3FW8p6EqgPIALeAN8CTT9To602m@cY6TR2BCxMq@j7zzTHfNcUCCT0AnYc/x5sUHzcs1amge30yRUd0Fu9VALTflJltNudVuXbR6mdY8mcXY6ZpWBxMV5KefGokD15mMQXds5qsCiNd0M1dt17r1pJzcSqXKggUJaen0nXI6ozFap5IG8FSq1UoCSQPqNPWhS/FNs2o6HREK8tE3wdCxrFRSvChD@t10O51JQtx0Mgs9Qz2ZBLrQmU@PFhoHJRgTPTCnQEpomNDLxic3qIyms2TYXD83xsOZGweIBv5A0cdB/MUCGlxnhB1JXFC/ZfHjOuXSYEOoejM40K9x/BBVtvGMdTAcy2lLWlquFXb9Z0J/5Pia9KkIdpsY67GTG0lJEKAzpiEMEy32Y9PDJqzZhjPx4oOdK8dgMXXwPRlOQFiGa@aywFXmmDP0oUOSm7uAnUQTTyj4cQ5NYDNxIYKeLsKJQhQVI5y1AQWHrnIyQS7S9WF0YEihmWCiJ5weKBTHb8QotRqNQ2RMyBzYjmsIQBKIwdElXXRxINcIJ8gP6eDbte4nCKW9KnZlpgES8YHlaJS2TFzHJqbGo1h8e4BRjo0eZ4H86IN4FFlduEZP2uLodLHjDqGHgNKgJFaj2hoFAZLjjXuiP4WoXAr7/HggMzBB7z0nPVVVi3qhXw3DkCuA2EOoJDSMbbCywyBBgcB0UMkHbGQqHCZ48vT@ARu@of099vA4lNcZOb0JqLaB6XZs2IMsOQB@Mm1nZAIZwvhvT61jx/HZQAM8rBscYna7OZpYGh12ujoydGM83ek6Fh2NuinqAn7iepqlsXGwMHTv08dgbjw/eVYXqzEgSTsb3Zg2DoWuTpbR8zA@@UknfsMZKo8xJr9Z4LHfCpefopgJAkoYEDYdnK4J/MvoP8LFpqCWBwMW9DHyDAArFBAXoOJqu8DzQpHn6L/W3IvgFArHdNRFri4Ulfqf@f3@kneOep8KKIKshXeeerOFqEvmaDxLBQaEq1KXYOKIihQmWpy6Fq5E4dhyGjGaxHwcrXoYGlY4i3kMmgnO1EHnbqH@BPYRWgNsAakByvwYJ2SoiMZpPqKDvutd01ahUY0FBs0lNmhDgU5MQtWF25RIMMxeo03FdoLpUY@JT8fNshGc7QabVkfzzWWWo8QmADY7gGK7UQtX@K0Dw5SSyQiMYqV5gxi0mHQlwbWiRutCPDquz9EoNc6TwHKZqrLQmpYO2pdJyaNk6BO@1ZrekdXPwATCpZqbd6WBUaOLqtbQqxaGJANdtTsjAmh2CMXGyPUhyBOSmS6TEupnYvcdqyewCTlgGMJMOaygYFVEtIQ0WClsmG64epQu32VRUY7GFp5ew3ulShvXAWJLVSNE0HwuyOVp9uySNKFrOxO9sWX6bTIXfaczDJZm2VcXtTJd03W1mccFi2rqZO/440@bcpth4EYaTrKVWS1Ow7XRoCCDQoQL18GFS4N806c9Pl36YGJ5FREyNaXzMZB9wMESqJEooaBEmPVL43JRlr4BRnHKwJx7s1GWGOm52Lc03zdsxnNspnM9udmUVJBMnSa/E8xvVIlMJ4FAAzUxDLJYI89O7h8cH4vAuV4qeYCTRVVojpo@BEVkXaFDSsYLXyV3eklyB@OkcYSAg6YGVkYniA9MXQOmBzsDUkfZMTDcFHimcZ5HB286tUYjMk0sIBAu8NJ9SqMIWcpIQ5kosurK/D@3mUkV5LMKHJ@hlARyp@5WgbZmWpzY5hvRgw6F6qcAEhil0C/UN1NUim0q6WAF3whnqcGSosohlKDZJMJbkHIAzJN2u8aWGwAsGlruAKnL87Qq6BL6uhJWfR28QXWhGILo9XfkZVMWKu3M5ipUdDVbsPqdlT@GFzEso/aMlclupmh7v9aQWR7YtCOT3M@p2XzldY8q2WQOng1vU/BwhRYVOnRB1/LCrOVlX9DIUJTQUR8sSCgSEsG7CQHP0nAq@cG2wWjUI5UmFxHRVSQ5ubykNCSbKqE0BJdCWGXMQysTBNMjB0rzKHgvIa4F0NYarFnBNtvi@NCcWp4UxhCmqktnV7RQ4YyPx2NaoGmfOnRqKXJ1ZFEpoOYXxR6dWtdj4qpXelkCjfLAYNV1ufNG3T69rACgMyzB3D31oGP3gc4LyqImHdMbHcZfkfLyepWlZIP1sLSnBTcR3twCKVTKFLjf7ZrrQIEIuBAtvK8AAyGF/KyKeVEJX3TAIRfoj0BwMStlUfSrS53IEt2DhbvB/b9@vQf0v147Q@gocJAzcnSg68aaEvprKyuIig/0srpi2Vj8xDI1Shjqug2lrrlQJM2KHKtR0/l@QYDuf4SzF0GNA2/iBbTGG9iM5ZxNPob31Ymsmr@zQWTq62CvLP1iSdGZJjDgepQITAkyDRqJii5WCcaUzfbETGkUY7dnKlyfRSgzs3ofTvwJu4LiemslmmM8b2qbAaRc0LqKIbGl8jdUuaudTnqOMD4dRHpqcQXsovR0ulkAdSCYee6gc3XxWQHZ0vPwvg5s0bVJ5/R2G1d49sQbC11qbffYE20IoxtScC12XQdiBm8LRo71VDMtevlATgywA6MECy8kXNwqxIhmXiGzpXVnqIMMvzyXRYsYQOLU9UxGzq2ZxR6P18dHS5LGr1RWx56KOqPHqrEAiS2gFdhoGS1wsKT2llqF7socaZag9mLOtcJ81RqIa6DR9CmNg2970Fc@bmRy7JD0iaW5C9cNLL7IRzhdsG7kOeg2jkzdAXVgTJSSqKhh1xHrMKjIDFfhLRLC9cv0EltpYa4iY/j@ihC5VosAR/dxdeoanvoAgcZWheLa2xiTiM46SunOOZ5r1YchmKbsurpHe7syVx8gnARLtzTox9d2B0uDgDjIeAujnpueQS@rCXu6MqO@bq30X24C4fBefLjuNrb2TMvxyDN6vYlAAxeowK6rGTpOS1OzBTroHXffIIPC5RSLCtWsgWMVywNJg8vaWp@4fZT7wf1DJVwkoRTlFgkVqj@OrQT3tXL9VHJPb6sg@oaki0tpY84buthVYiqYY1lfOjAMcIJudckeyGUaU5TYUN@ahHFq5Vybhfefo@tYR9qw6xjPqDoN2h1GqJTB4btMxf55UsvfnFrvw4TSNbSl2woRq9xTy4DOil6vVSlRZeVLxlBk@cNFVN@aGBNjpaHxtPvawHf6bzAyPjxTclCMzWBEHicB8F2YCOptYBl@UK6xn8anG4WJZpm6cbsqsyzUxqB9j9F0PgLHETquxxjYk/FSrS5ZZ/bxzSQbjsMm7fSWcochX1YOlW/RlJb0c8@g540WE7PwcC1avSDLcqDAxGZWlh5usqRyUdzXJrsuJUx9FikvYHE2zY05V6dByRJf7bhWBKnrDHsKXKlItmkb/gyvHyhNu45jfZmaAqGKbyg7YK0KdFXvTTV2Td0J3lchi6ELDwc8uv11gxastwlsS6APGs03VXp86ueDalPAyc0RTjwtP65OA4clLW3U7Wkk1T130itUz6Uk8FVaHBBii3yt9YpkMBSiiGWxdGOTY@qp0zUsjd2mxfxN@Cpi7kZ8yxIjmJHFGVw2b7uYb09ckUjjGVDK7IGJMjRGBn28QcXXerg5R3BbCzR18FwXPDUMXZoeGPo6gLEJQsHG69JEcUxT8h0bjCsf1xOikWLhitXAd534Daf8VhL5cKQNDLZbzE1icjFagUtmmE23cK4et6iyZTI6RFtsA7KeJaBFnRozL7yvRPh4pkO9Tka3j7Vdafk6DoB@QFNft1T2ev9qD52hPTSGbH169LSucQA/@mx3n5uyDrkeDHHJ3Hi8tJQ@Tk/LsawPoSfKRSYlHae/Mk8H@KotviH2pfCy9/qD260jd5rPZAc61raaoTGBTslzfGdsCPRpHaiFozzsuk6AhjPUP@/w0Y1GPlAkvP@8@G81LAea44/H9NYZWxOPXmhUgb4hfZvS1GfrT@jiS8cdiG@dUVcMPMVgcQqd/14tYrqmrw/xFXXG2cbA6epD87ZMB9tiSOF4D3v8IMMVKWMS4T56i5YJ5HVnIvJLPR7@DG@H6yo9GDpiPVvkuEFZWTU8R18CF8baqe6xoVB0kSqOBsdaI3tVvEpftq@@mZj@AmlswVI0tsvmJNCxLu/B0om1ahV9F2MhhoMlFWu5lGroqI0LhgzajrIu2eXFbLEmlsuxy7oMxUtJcxRblPJlyB0s8KFDg2Zs0Bb8l/hraWXSyk7OHk4G3nWBycbqe6Cf4WX9mAVdMx0br4Y@S7OD2zoyq5aEL1PCvQMK18S4cUKlcOOMCoVTLEFzTLh14AZVN1k7gGaZY49didBfOw8XLFgCQ/zqZCGjzWy1JR1UTM/os/kPdN2mhY4cF5cbgw4i6DiNjsPnKMyZ4sUEl@0MQKgLFlkAh7Dr1JaVa4RWV3/UZwqfPTEGGi6ofmT6uCJzBVdQll21tuhW3F@baJ75tQmUbB2z4f4QbA7SjW8hgE8r8D3WBqb@cKkiokwGBA6Wc7LbEvuj1/W6OB@aHi5nihw3jEohyzEmRq7rgNGwAvLqoH20NcaiAbHXLVdCrxpYd8YzfCttRl03jambPh1iDe7r7MZ1K8BuzMT5ZDSeeMFtdR7ogqn4EPTolPp75yYgF96AaCVDzfJXD1PHxltBCws6xYVznTb@uWk5A/J5WSagtIEShsr5Csa5B93zEa7Gce0VnEjT/sA5TxzlEFxWsDdQtwa@PGGb/s1DOb6PK3PCOxaG9Rz4GoL0CK/i7pfFIJyspsij23X9xSvQt/TvwHnPnImrG@iM9jWJmwVBqsZ@uMQYX9twcF@W87iVpjsWNC9wWCubjO7YE19wJ/aNvULxxl6hintbxdiApL528Ph5Os4NdEn2bVpouPvZwrV2tcAVJjNtUMTWy9Fl6NCWuM92ZTqm64FvibOHW0fpVFzfd1bZO0cz6EA@2GAC4T8Z3Td0nDO8Ne0nzmPHdqA3GoOgHB0bbG@BpVUeqyNitEf49jzQp3drMs8o2jWdENM2tLHRhfq1Fq4P6YsY4vuar63piujAILX/ItetvGJaXcN9TUf8Yu51Ju1yhh4aU2pbrGcY1gYFX9eZSoyDcUttZGm6xhs7js2uVNrKcFMe3yxVoCuglw@fJRdxtf3SuMBK@2y5qE/P2BIRo8c2v1hXVtfoOha73rAgyTbZggDNNQ1PeoR7KVC/Yp4IoH15N8qQ0o0yZGEagSZ7pnl0hn61qbFAqUy/xPqfoebqDk6DBY4blubENkC4RUxHC/jZqoEuEH4KEkvTJ8HWpLdlyxp1R/Sy1mCI1eax0cVXf7p01xBfm16vTDYyFGyZEFvOFW00EIorbNRFkjoCayR9e7e1ZEctU9Uc0wuV1GvnyulKHcE2Df2thqNmDqXXYmB6KRzKLD2hzjUD1bFmRIeQJY2@Ub@yJS2vWwOFxjIEf@iCzS/5N41th9u5rJgMmYwMnGFenoJZq7o63pAW1lk9mR4JV9cQgp0FQZZEuwwy/VDYW6t5Inr4P733iQSdcKeYD7c4AdF1@/Q9ZH7i2sHtQzjwyPH8vjl9CvnGVwDWiRMsVgGiwI21DHRtrSsE1J49sdjowyC26GrUo@aYQPd/FgSLimvfEAz7TKAbzk2vl8hhb3ZJe7hXsG/0hGC/BZxmEB6FL3lFYMF9xexpXDbiSk9FYoSdFvPB2s9VxD0PJQPoW44vjD16l8be0eGjpyfi2FNW9k97Q3w14poet7SBg1qWY0NSrzU3NtnJ1qL1TM@X7j1ThP1HhyICrKE3m9EQ4IbTcku3teOe4Z6xkrbWCsJQw1@tID48efwos3gPk6T2h64zMtLx4P1nz7L4msknz1YGx2M/gNbRd6Zrox8eKEp6Bfs@t@nU4DrpuSKldZhODLBGgRkfsv1fblWudGds9E5mY@NT6DxRgnsfmHxxbSGfaGfmAFshqawlFG2opCIW8@nYsmwwtg03uq@rz1NzjNJSpzeJ3dauRUHNISe5udXaw03T/Ve1GCIHyxC@XCRFvs6t8V2LJc37u2ZMUZR1dH6m9aFeSWFtZS0DrJoctpyzD5hHNgLjRYi8BB@4SjBvXUReEkYguiW84PB84AnO7to1MDchiLyLKxv8uWHPNFugc1k3qRdViI0r2m4E@dz4gAmpaHnPGW6NvnKOL1pPT1I6daZvSfjEjUXZ3793eFuE44CWN0N9/OQ5OdI83OzkZsB4jo0PyPFCM3ot4LgV7rS3djq15wIq9UZ8g/Hq9lwlzzS359iz6e2TcPRFU@za6Wa0ES58okCGZU7NVX2Vzsa1jlavMbotbfYGhzNb0oPjm@AEiN5/618qiizTLY7wrsjs8ZaaCRs4SaFLm@G@efGgk8NINOiot4jgkV5pjT4yprgWhY0GrzLqV/ZvxRv6vlJ6fXdyU1j5hrD8DeldC0NPkhNl5QaEhRvCSEGMgh851vnQEfc11/BWrABZmaGbClK5oSCVmHQO9manE4uBe72Kj@8tBLeV3Hpi@G5@PHS6Zn5lGfb6uJkleYxbs18PD5ZTaC5d3jJwgvc92PPq9M4nxsqEHmtvVwdQSXO6MgiEoDGc0PchrgcvT5B2Qec17IHJ9nEk9xz/gD7dYJhFrzuvXotgju9PxutzDLIRP4BxVZwvAb4Am9k598g9fC9uoaavsP1xcdxq/3U6LYkGBnE704cneyF3PX0mqbEUF7n47GjJG98c9Z8@i/m5xnS6zugVputsyJUhi1SfnOSXkt1uvDxbQaz1LxuBugHyOLqv1YOYsPvk2XWRgObb0B9ZYcgnmr0YMV2qsJ7j09cMVwYezaZ0DeXKmh6yJWyrwlz9tvVj0CGbJqTtSZ0O7rnU6azjyhPjMzr3AGoQ8ZlawpAGuysZ0/wwzCGNsrahOqcL5Wcpu8/GQ9OergwarYtDl5CmXnurm8EeeWY55@RRtHXQOvGgrkaunRn2OuG06k1FoZK7WQvLXVGp1tUL@1ZKcFtXJffWKWpXZAYuiLhJmmD8Y116ED58qqZvhf/kWQh@O@y@5eD4fc@cjG4HpmgzmdsB3RvE31WE5u1g@GmR06Hj2reDhuxUrd4zPjATGx8MOZrpzgfkodvv3w504Dm3Az2eWL6JNstq0CfOxMLtA1aFHbiDlf6N7UarJVbFdYG4a7s3dNPrw3FdpDPxwAYyI@EZRRRem/6SZ8gzcT/cRN6wRdtJX8H7iUO@itvFryDF2w@so08erINbnrCZ4BQ/fR144Vz3auh4lru1kb81B/ThQxqdbY5uhF3s63foOjZ7Sq/rHhd7/K1I6aFmmbcKtHDBg3rL0gfs0Fg4OcvdLrVAQXiwvs4@nU0X5uZy6S2248SqsH0ViDLQ9XT4vSNcl67kYoN@bP2Z4a0f9qO9/9cORpruhYyGXmx5QTiB7K3TBOIjCMsd@rMn9/ZOXhw9Whn6VW3UXS3pw4@CqPcXe@OtVWyjYVb6ERXpGV4Fb6iBUkVHWAXc/OLKjPyLvUdHq/v0IRi0UJ@462lsWHrRJad6rqeNKvnVNfg4fMf0PggqdK/sQthGDqAKxL834mWD7drYxidsuwlPDD8Kk0rZIDHSy9/hi@@dgbvypzZxV@pNuk8GwF5eko1gbwoI4MPdLoLdOHDzWtOeGLidBvs6l1/fhGTqdaVQITv44bsqUWSaJn7Xs8L2CA0Ta5LNi2CniWpVmZONOuGrPAn2@oi2/Gfb1gNi3HAbCkWEU4Vs@hCyGe5TQeh3mMgloSPsgo77GsOTKMV37KkFO3lAnjYvjg6PDp6d7J08f9aU2/Ngp4@wFLYNqYX7Cd3J9XgofEA3sNzZRyzoDjMWJEc/voMj815YLoLfnVsuWn2paItC8TsYZ/PCtiWJbnYiCXPIn8Cz1Ggo6p/gxXCHJaYVFOxzU2X7jtDtU6COGGqepgmVViXyqoTHGlihm3YQfvUzjTQUP@lZxY96YsLBdweAEweO0wtS9Axy@xGm@GDv8NHz4wMSZnDBNedmzx/WKwX2WQq2ARPUU9@kC8DrJBlESUJd1evJB0kgTFJMkirdnoZ@EgIYHcBC6uDGNkHsLZLapPiBgsmoUqT/@nVpnhTxRaY0wCbDTCUhWeB5yigbGxvkBJiE3D8@/PTgmGD@D@5TbyQRoiAnuDfGn/64xz6qFO5RF37O1B0FJiPUlueYvSpuWKMbJJFX1GDXqx7BnRrZni7EmNIPFFHOo8NosQ@cpukOYlx8l51w65nF7jhYc1QCxGOyjx/RXWeiry5FH4/jOPppLuD3c7oz7pUtS9N0F0H28dZgR9kQNWW98AMuON2Ou8NiJ2Z6Ju55g/XQx81alxsJrtCleySLZA@/9Irfk9Xo98EgsxPbZxsiBtulJYBDxUhWZckmzSz7mhgfA0xub0Aj6RoD0yaebYIe5FfJa@BgnNKusj2RBKGRvBYlRF2lLgEt1xjgtd1dPanlSu9/9Z9LgxoBtw/ubwfuqXwPnn45eOqD@1eY@6WEDHp9N9hFXuIZwk2kgxKwjHB982c/w@8886lNRTntuGeZZEGuwUWpFUiB3NlsCcJmU67vbmpASP/NtAXNWdrKnxn3h/3e4UBq8TwoPXlJ2rq4uEg@2DoyXxZIUeiZavHNdDbPFXNvpvOcUn5zOlaKTfHNtM2X69nTdqvZJkdHn73rvEvz07PZG@h3UsBg@095Jc8nqhVysVPMJU4r@AFJKOEpeQvHaZ/gn7rf9mJuDd3dPvBtkieJVgs/2MyXeBB7yTb8qaR4BQeTGc2G2BB32u/epZua5k@hjzfNsdfrwekMSUpV088INLW70IhYBIm06J0SEY7CaNon0z1jMJgcaDNz8sDfFUtiWVRjgmn78ecvgqP24vlzQp6T58/fHq8RY@1MJiUITeqehp6PoJvPTkm1oxUS@AnIP/3Jxjx7cdTZ/tNvjCRjA29P8fbt@WN0P1MKdzY27ty7l89nVVVl7qPPj35xb28vfz9bOGoWdvKCvLH9J3@8saGq26q00fY8pZ1snp5@xqtynhf/9EfJztHR1zyvkfs/v/6uoeClBJczUiIVPHJEASdey3AqpFAgH3ok3iYUOBIz@uskQv@LDaI0dkr/7btP3yT8REOVXrhw9xNvEsVygjnBAU@58Oks0UhsI1hxnphJ9XodnKX/9u8hfuMTwIMhs224NAohruIs0RDqNMplolEEh6KqkO7//fWvx3II8gxESZ22yPDYBYHYbPL5ksrvtOHYosc2h1uFCbIkhXC2P/QNhyjlu8pdfDDhAW62gXsrG34rgR/BfbpLxJfHGegTMuKnjQ3p/rYAhziWFEVtKcpdEL/Cna16XYB@hTbbXK5wFzduTdPecOD4DjHuvlg6Ei/@Xo6VaGov/j6PY7Jv6obrZLlEcWP31f1GA8qba@S2Ghl6BI2MtrdSmXecXZA1J8OJazr4Nd3aI/wuVIOXyyqfzWZ3jzsQhUynSEJhOhU7iALaLfaSCXaIHcJ8sDkHnowX4WigJGiTyJ/FCh8XcORVsgltpP1qPVziAI8/@9/@7Ht/9l36@x49/xPus2b3zL60BUBn0FwacOxWq3qjwTdc/qKFzw3gMblarpalzryV2mo22seg1n58mSzkkuSZNct2sNmQVrrVpPEbNNlGkDw@NxIL7wbzacT9ggAGTD3gHlCKJMJyxsoVUY2QK3BcIlyUJjTPGm0BBznrQlMpFtoCi9Xchcrh1VKF77QTwuYMJJHabqgF9SnZbbCDDDc94mBucmoxLEiQ38aibIuQxVMj7pVohNEaC5gvCxfkqcIlmk2pbdC@ohFmdHejulGuFquq1GmsP2qLGHhQUMMwjrzEWSI6aiTgw5CeiYgzY34v4zURVQsJGZgsxb0FDuoKhMZ0GvzXHLS6ckWFrwUutcOTGvCHmhPUQYeXFWhtu51Ied@BYwN@9A9H9IjXDeoTeFOQ68cGqSpbak4q3CkeqNj1Xj1codnIUMkotBsZESWkIF6B4aAvIXq3232rd0Ez0bSupmuKr020qTbT/O6kO@36@kTHj6STI1TvOgEZ3JxTcMpOSBVRSOQKymbiLpYtp1bwe@Ngm5TLuYqaKym5UjFXktVyIVeu5Er5XKkECHMlNVep5FU1VyzliuVcsZgrVvCb7gBTBJgcYigVcpUcl3jX3CDHTL5NSSY8Wplbj@cilWh4UIeDpyA40wQoTridOJf4BzgaiqqQLegcZbiARkidRKU/KOG@Zk68LEcSoOxdtN9tNd9tkXhtCUGe4SZ2dtsZYT5vgrtWC/7bjchZowdzQVHb80xm@2UDdKCXjWYGUL4MUIoCoUjFToO0t2lQlFqQXBC@3QY1SshsN7frzj49RdoUhTag3F7K5u4u5atdiNnYhCafzmQ2BWGjCXiaQW8EwMh9QXkAUzsFusrFxc95kmTeSRad3e1tECvz7Xlj3tyez7e34b9Nr/PgDr7z7Wt/elsca2AW4W0USa2m1GhJrUAsteFZlBroI0otcDTgDnDNnFpuY0eIio7Y/sf5F7OLa@SDWW6LkGsusUW2Eri9WC6xxSVevf/if8Gz9f6L30OllcDPqHKJC0K4hLRVIdSP3iqguT22yWN22ODGM3xEH/RoPEZPm11sNIUl6ZVIqgL78oJSLqZF7Ok7Tr@DLy2L5BWAAtjBwID2EopZwqvlIt/JKDOVJLb5YolK1l@4diSTyX/ySq2UkszcxrduX3me9ziWy0U@AbimyoqgXDbYrtJso/9fWHX8k19Yd3CJywpBGqUIowuXADZKSBKYiVyisT3CVZn43SEBPyB5Vv9MeL4n4NcyNJ/a4zhYB1pB/fCgXqk00E4yNo9o09m6vwVXBf4HG1AI0uoDaKtf10egg7f6uYLaQrP0Yw3Mc5BpQvcN/h69xR850fF3/AZ/5OQt/o59/JHHXfydvMHfXhd/JyP83XuDv8dv8fd8gL/WV3I5pcZvXlDyZJSKMt@c8pRMNejOGq2v@O6sSj@ewas7KuicwddLUrl8JZ1ofYUNnFSDb33gSllD92tavVLr1tUANFjmgyGi6YVfJ02xF7OrKknjgEWuUnBcAeek4QIemVxFcdzkT7/zjW8k6/WkkKTfPciDn9BFoC4FgkeImWc5we/JQf6g0j0vWdtNfqVJB6cKlXYTA9sQwCXqZFPZVGRL1mWlq3TBYRLZJfJQHio9hdptskHkmTwj8shReuAy4CeDy5T7RB4Q2ZZtAINQcPkd2UdXH24D@PUBkQs/E5c7dRVZJ5CQhUoq/cSb0sGY8mWHfDx0PD87bnFNkiT8KwMMcFERZbFotvHrFE3@1auWtNVWK2UiIpOLnearVrLNt3jcyVit5El3Zmy0XvGglcg8awzoQxKeB1Z9LSG1WhKrACAbrdH5vNM5eHK/05Gwe2wRo5HZzYC4392tg/gPbjuJRm2nVaW9R9iDJKTtnVYjJ6C7mIG@QQU/8tCwDDsrZb7ksUAM98YGJUD71fkrMIJS52gKnZ/B7Tx0vGjBpcOMJBosnb9oxR6pAw6ElaQXKzAsOSDXtgtmA1nofvAHa/If6m/@4/o/fk7SJNVsp1MX8@0UPdL4S6cv5hfz4NpIp1LBQ2obfugBzxjlYt5AJwW6AFczlW6n53PmB9dUepshbEAy2w0adwEHnUwiSpImyy6pv987JB0crWSNvOK3t139slWj0iAvV0iCf1Uj2mKmodWaynIaJFawzbpgk03tkg7Lpmv0W1qb3abS/pMf0a30d9IUqJCv1ZQtwh7UvFqr5cOnUrlWK4cPm6lU5frRkHeUIthO@Xw6XavBw06IVoZHiNsk7zKkTlpwbd@9yxIpq5eXIc5cvpiRcYanVgtTKkCyhqfpTHyDHnr4lG5DD9KikCAoFEgwSJ2S6XcsUKwn@Sp/924q@Nzzzl767l21Il9eRj7jMXgpS16dTs90Ox30z11e8h2ezg5UCvAsly8vFbmSUZIk7bipJ/g1LUgrJSjkjtqgyVZAZqv5EgQHOShsbxfzjUYxDz7FMkSEQjGJXSNJPlnjExe0GEq5xOQYX0NvkoAGDb2mdzFP0Jok@UI6BTIwDVrlPIE/F8Ul664KhXQtL8uJiznPgJVKhUGnSb6YKmcqwa@@kSYNUJnYD/W@XCa/VdraBQ0af9501YEStXZh1JV5/cKo4meL5jU9@CIqvsht3L2bqwBpynKC3J/gdhLZFheI4zp0TKh9waXFJZMZcucuh2@5u8lqbZfWrFIukESyxjyFJIh1UgYaS@pWQSkjTTizj9szgArBKdQW3SAbnErveOEqzELdQE@wfeOyj/65HhykR7pkgAcZoO1JTGLRg1iEhdOrrkdADjuC0OiRxsUj8jGigw255wo5xqVJ8miimzjsdfRob//gJKtuCyShPtjbz6rPnt9LKPhYWDzT4Bw@Hx/s3X/6HCIcPTrYe3bw8eGnB8@PwN8j54sj6iXCviLqM2KuFc/n5AX32n2rGYZmTAyjcz6ZnL8hr02zY0LVWhMomzNwiWd0oEhjbVG8Gpy66WmvX2vumB7k/Q@@9f4H/937H37n/Q@/9f6H3/vpF9/7Fpw/hvM77P6df1cp4PWnX/zL33n/2z8Ez/8E5x/C@ZOffvEbX2cnff4jOP9LzO@PgjMGx04OcP3yT7/47o9@@sWvfB/Ofx2c379@/upPVp/f@@b6E@N993duhvnOv4fzdxmuEPY7v8388H4N/rcZ3K98//2v/wf2/5Pgh84fvv/1P8JL8PAvvv8n/@X9N/6jqpb/5N@@/@Z333/zG@@/@e333/yn6vvf@LeKHL/8zvvv/f5f/sHv/uUf/I/0/2N6/d0P@b///r/48//1z//3P/@D4PwJnP8BXD/58/8IzfVvfv8H@P/u7//NH/4A///zv/mb3/@1v/nl/4k6fpM5/p9//e/Y9a9@9T//9W99@y9/8vW//rWf/PVv/v5f/h@/8n/9xn/@q//@9/7qn38DPX/zJ3/5h7/8F9/41l9881/9xTe@WHP91o3XLz7A/4t/AJ8Pz@eH4PmQcn1Zny9@rvz8XaixSAX4BLj7n73/jV8CBv91Qt5/68f4QgSca/4/VhUK82P29P8Dh3q9zBgigwvOX3v/re8gif4HIBH8I3p9O3pYCmEP3148AFl/a0Wkf/bTL/7Vj@hTwqg26LQU9uRltZzZAqNnq1IJevNgxgqi/NIytghBkNK3UUIthX0bZdv7H3z9/Y/@6fsf/Ob7H/wy9uFCvpLdywrKLdN9AFj4ADgELH4IHAJ@Bul3MnQUT8h8Bk8bnxXKOdu2a5999hnXuZTwzZvdS/IZ/Mhn4UFYEL6ZEwSFYeiPr@oQ8G@@etXGOeKYn6Qw5JLK7kEQrv6BlAT1TmZHUlQWZFxKmywWqYFHrpxrxbIu9ftbVfgRuFSrWxdZYacFiiCNOueMsEhKgHVDIoqWzW3lNACU8gyOVO1dOZ8pbWkaWLcZxJuhqtBWqKAVcmSaCZKcBvPI6A9A0y3qnBI2FTClwVNuSqeb4V8ipExyhNjsX@NIhmpN9MDPk4VO6gjihVPV1MkVIJnMYqKBaoyEKWtbzIdOwNN082Ch0Nm7zBQscnDg6DgE3QODoF7PYMQ6yyI8ssI0yoRmJZOpQ7kxNouT7ZQRxfQexQIx65lj0tmqT1nEDOJrhOTIcOh1zCsqnynX70OC9el9grgQOUX76lW9Ua5PG4juHaNOZpq5R/OEyOqZaeMdPNcpTojHJe6/g6yU65lMo4wJYiFZ9aARjpVUoIWjZcfZX1YHcMclWDu7hNzhlTLP5lg2kGAMGq@ZBTQCAjiEtzJbQXHoP3TSc4sSfIMmFaRCWPgOVZV3mPaMAIBXEERRJHDiwoYdsgvBU4YqQ5OFW4ZhyFCOoBwQeRBKEy5D65cRCNIHb/qVVqKq@RpYHzWCXq7O4Yfd6GoZmduc4kqoCxJoynLwfdI5pwFMXs5xF5dasFJqUyNz8CpyCEHTrG996QMzi8Ta3NzkEg0@xz@lc8MZSSLuaZWud4OWS@2oKuGLFR69Dbr4jxHvMa7pznLUXcNikvdf/1EiL5cS3GaSfl6bsITInQw7d3e3yB0gK73H/KZ0WZmQyTl5J8HIuJ3J8Cok2nDgaYuSMEOxcS9Joo5/8E9QxiIJcqS5ppflslQkZuEm1hMYTJ4@fRrkl3q8rHMZaHFqTsFnnBecTCYQ3ejhHHw2K4pZMZsN7iK9Uw8xcIg0NLiLm0h6Erf3lFIZPwJr60OkC/fu3TvgDQ5pUT0EA5w5SV3Nl2kgoWwwxQVf2ijLsa0YLGsWritV8xWOjVYQpZgnJEU5Ao40wQWUKWDtNMdWYTH2Co9UUi2DSY2QUGNiCsAYmqKCMomtVKVv5pBCaekRchZ/xDFINu6NiwOiJaIsf6lyIR0G7j8l@08fPz54cjJutwln0M8PG52x6@iG56UwbO/Jfca@aqWYTjSbWPaTqooykjuoysjGmcP7x4fPqoRRLKi6FC1Hjc6rB3SpKFxiPH6xnXBx7N01ePyylsM/w2t1QYqUWgH5nU40uIRuoFEGfIp/OGvk2Bgg@z72BvecKUnJWZ7PKkU0mdM4TQzZ@UVnQnAHSLZdBEgHXM0nQnkx540LITb7hB4NcqxyzCEo1EFylXLoKDGHUioiwFP2aboc13h2cAKYT54SRZVFcux0TchU4zMyFWk@j52R4WSFOY2NEunEHDkIYdUtwx74w038wC/fkvkYgTabchZ/ai4HVyVfzCqFUntjw7oQEE@LsswFrlWcw@OFgDT5CA7CfcSRj8ALDmFOOPx4NwkG@Q@f1hjz4ou2JAW5f@a7vFIAuZDmcL4iwMeN40cNiA7tbHnij0tsfP65TxqNgyf3hcMHODAxHZJwoaNg9sShSBmnN3ENGjogpGd@auJH2MSe6Y0tbQaNGOi11QCC@DgBm5jP533AefiAqA2VPrK4PbzOderTBfd8qnEEBHSfS9wNx2K40t1qtf5OyZcgb9Xqu5yqcuDBbYFWYfY3gNvoopUtif14u55X5IwSznSQNM/zNQ8ylcuVpS0uofA83HK5HEcbEOGqBkfoUqZ3cr0uBDI@r9CVTBx@CECb1tXoCGCndxawOZnBYggEkIHvEjkMK7Gw4CnsFqAouLaXfne2FkgU@e7dHI5I5fJyVHZCSUPmUKWbuXwOKwn8wLedyJeCKTQoXzvBWYZPenVwJ1pYYNaYlQRP8AnlX64sc4lmApo212w36//f/9pNrj39x/sHsjSbdW4KEjJ@Bt4IQ@9k6cdxj52ni//Tp6P4443/0VPn8VNn5MAfesLHKMBri3@ttvR48z@QnCiUaqAKc74xBXaCX14ucP8ID2jglInZfO12sNFkg66tbiqVfPsAGkmTtLfDPSgbAL3NXp8huPlHncciSr4ZvFLT8AyrL@KK5Tq/PW7kZJXfDna7bpBPDRuFUBC/0av3HJ1@1rvWE038vDq@s8Pi5fN8zbFx@7h6OCkKPVX6YlA/p68V14z6QMQNSVxbsyB61@nNRM@fgYqhO5bj1pNgbiXDgAVyA/RwHIHeyeXyVSiYOHbGO6DMfWo6lgbqCAfuvZ5jo6KkFkqZpiKDEoOnUs6q2Q1jp1Sq9kTdMjR3p1AtlLPwEE1n7xTk6kD87PGjh74/PoZe1/D8nXwFIuDGXrgFz065WigA//J8pkkTb@MXjFknJWxsgFA3tJ4Ad5zt9gS13IbIPdOt15PJnZyiCko1J5fnXERUrI@h0sjL@W0J7mAxSjiLDr1rg@wZAwO7QVoRyrY0xioGJ4Bq4OyCs7AtdcFpgrOyLZngnDRyirwtTVhNI0UbHGYqg5TMYm1nh8pF0L9Ubcc25lw1q2XNC0r4ar/fn29dZBYPnHYhsCeokrmgZbsX0WNNiMFVySQrmItA8NH6UMMXwSKBKq8WynytWVs8l4p8rT3ndkdGz9Tw@9Yt@eJ6rCL0@wxrAhJqEW5edR3Hr3aNvuMaC8CcUgwBWYauA@T5eZRcS8YUL64nV4wBTS@uY8kX@HkUK8wWN59DpTJ6Q4t8@ZJLbB1/mms0gEEu8iU1X8gX1FyxWCipoKtU8sVCGSpVLsoFVYWWmq@UK6U5NBFJepeg33Aj@xdh06nSjexTWpXtxNhsk/S7J6Z1Uc4JrK2n0jXo3BLvuMSd40/VRmP9YEoK9L5PVaFRzxUq4MqhS83RrlBVBTUn5BRByeH/FoeK/w@HV@Gv4hVi5VTuBPdneQIqF2ibNnmE@zz4DjlxHPqKyj1DXwOxP9ToXjD7ruN5fweYe5p9yoLum2xT1CjooYbfOvNGpj9cA/F8PMKtXQz3HwzDwagLGUTRygDuwcW1HGcVQIk8P1pTysfRNuRADLYPOYAfH3788CR2PznY23/IFcm9p0/uX7kVAqACeXTw4CR6LLHQMGohQvGLB48eXX0Mbvmnz4/7E8fFk3vw9Hl@cYm88M0eLg/HMlDkTZEEF3zEHhsVS7IBFl7oUDh8qehuvkLuBs5CceGU0fmCvbZketF7R@zNtyp3Er7LpNGXTLsG0dkOPjj0RXfXC4xQpVThuDGxnXNSkknPsSwNP9ze3wDPoeaRrmGgTWVZyImY9LnjWr1zs2dsgKYDaVQU/Eg2ZoJ7CEhGE52@HA46Le7V2sNPquMEc9eaGGQyJms94YZe6HTNwRC69XMnBOC6mkbg/LIHxDfih3@zh8/SoH7XQqzr4FyC23uKxnIlwfP7PP9Q87Waa5ReksbBFDgV2o3mzrLlbI73C3zVHuCEpDVG89cbN7cmoKZvbIAN/1e/9eO//eNf21Fb8r6MI6mPH@XVGWgcilTr1olSvGzs5J1d1OddtBC3OkaiPKhXvUJR2ZGwU3XrcmY3MXa8h0a5xvNgKYM0rXpoHj@g37I/sE2QJQ/g4HnsP/XTfe0lWK2dLOW9KlXA7juuruHqWLSkCLWLAoNKpHa8WikXypWcWs6WK@V8QSkWCllFzSqlcqkC2ZKVslIsFypKtpyvgOKUr0BoAUxpZo5J0hbZs3D4JctMLmmrCuhtHb8RvU2HBMQh2P5sAQN5m9LSJKFFzxPCGxCHJ3v2wLAAB47k@PTVui2zDj0yUWSSKxHArBGdJB482JextPfwAZd17cs838OHQlmWS/d43qAh@2XUDXmHxSnjxnu8zx5k@R5U6oQhwD3reX6IDwdFHIrneRMf9vcYVfv4oGJ8ADtlIezBCh9KAGbjA9iHFMGbCBuA7bF08jSjB/iASWLIAxayD2E8/3GYHQw5ZmAMwcOwpHt7PH/IHvb2MGSfFrvAMvpVfNijB8@78AAtjucH4Bi40NaBP8CJ7Y7ndXDpMw388LvcuK257Ws8P2PkQQLx/JRCa/opz3dCf0zm0yA3BaRulT4orNS79KGCP55Xw0wjWC56yPF8PnrIQ9kePvxUG/o9Y8COmcvuOpT04cOcZk4nBw@6H3/cHQy67mzv4ONjDNrffwjqzWzidgfdIGK3A4cDsfYfqtrpaHb1gFIfdjpVzVoZ9NVOJ6/ZV4I6s46BOYRYbyBnwTHAhEadfQjaf9jZ1VYtSKEIOyhyRnDv4nFvBPd7WpcFhQcNovdpt8vXoBmAfdBKcWj54JoSbJ6nIMLt7EjTXaeGz9M6kenK3VmzKLdrNICMwHSRa3MM76fwquFoafpi1pzW5XZ9Wi8FC0L7Kb41VQsmn90Y7SiVQnVD21HUfGZaxbeCnX6SJAVlh6SUu1tvSepJekcFO2aDb@3sCHxTae8USy9RvlXxsqMq5WpeVkmaPeZKVYgjJ2VC8JJulto7pUJ1EblUymiSWi2VQBsE@vigU3RxfLJDUqlzQztNpzHrdIALykMLTma00Gatn5pmp3WWSTJL16Z1pcb29iXyFWypVA83kp/ouH8oYUgHgHC6I1dxMVOKVyplHvIgSak0CKP5fM6Ic5EH0@fiwru4aM0jUSmBazHE@OJrJ6cnJ5@BtAKlZZalemkjGJw7cg2UebXg8eOH@@Lh0/AJ94gXH6C@7LjiPsq4pRCmOIdeJ2AFiQ@hpwcDNvSDOL7rWOIBXfULSncYEG6xIAb7tYonD5fwPBs65yxliOTV6KZ/@D42bqFv9ohWb4BL65EUzRXR0udUx@g0GvVOfWSMxv4MihjG@iqh@8sv0Bx6LO/0EyC4kRqNftF3nVEQ0KnLc@jwpompIJA9UAEnbhYwdupEUF6NnN4rNaPXeriH/r36PURT68C9Cya44bqOy4PJydf6O3Z9Ynta3zgyXHzJ/PDpJug@uEdDqk@M9CZpHSD0PppMc6HhEnuRxyeTUUoTGt30shcOaEceSKbU18LiX@CALuSc5@e1fp2kXgLoG3h2N0mqJ95L7@RrQLF7pJMGL/lV/1WfqKSYr1HLKIW4oAlSSiEFtHS98VVQ2RjqU1KtQm6CKj8FrJgYIIbaoCFaemzOa3rdIimBTNOURvnaoN7E6Jd42RZAxxCE5mUbx6NfoLnwZgKdZwOae22W0OrepEu/wkLkrqLKxdoU/JRSvjaE@tZeTmtufTxxjZoFj8EINqEl1mpAWyAhoHl7mXr/S19PbwuFOvOrUVSXqK90xE59WrNxX0fglHquDgGZZl7OFsqgyRRKWVAh1GJWKWZz2XxWKKEv6A/ZQhY8wTID/ShlpXhC@Kw8lUUlqxhKNiW/Mnuv0tnTlAx0oMRLZ33nwJ6MCPpAlSG30me4a@mMugUk6jlE2xYo84KQqWG5gPZDMjazQ4rp2NAsFiEtkNxWytpMIdDmyWR80GxXqwfT8dcgKCW82SlmSnLmbTpdS22k657xho723zOBQTQgLkomWvzxBvB0MMpPvMmoCbUOLqWkVpvNLpa1JGdzcg6KaXYuB9t8g29n5Y2iAnU2pwNiCmGSJT6wDZoTt/Abd9B0sAyoQ6Wi1jgRx5MT5J47oSPtubIqVKTCVkFmo9sMBTcORCTSlqRafPDKQDKVTJbUZHJhZ6eTNZxG3OAX8zrU@qbLPVNJENkkeVctFHd4UAD5Kl9ReQBbSFzMJZHDnG@Rfc3wNBdnADjUgkkerPcLbn4x325wU5E7GJmWqWWJber4zTNTPxU5VGGzpGsOSF/zsS2L3B6U9rAqcs/AFDSoq3mAW9ETFp9ur4DR2gHCKp0d8YezoQH2kcjN6GSRL173hVoieA@TWoYgX@Ge4dv52@pL/JVePt57ir8Huwlco092vwJhFfAvv3z8/Onzpw/oG9iLVyS/zLHLEYkuxAc1vZao0VFdnEGHZJhS/@HHLs6eEmkDXzImGVEQG/T19V2WSivYSEXaIOTLvimQ2W68ZPcWvncGqDm6D3aTtOkKXsNES558qoFCuUOSUOWaO2qqaq7dVEuglkDX1ZQZqKoqNchFJ0HfmGwAf08vINPbmQa@pP5VMptpGSEs@l3SGGQ2ZXWWOOvwxUqOvlHdaSjyKdlI3t3CT2YLJHF2utFQtzLJo2ouk7yfzOUTZ6nWZiOjzJIS2cqosz6uNcI1K1IS4FRj605uK/k8Uy0PslUlg1cVrtUkETYSu53sbrricZSTSWKJwBuVvfre4HgvGHQne/uNsjoLXq5PvOzw5VKQxdYmkEzNvNxdit8AXeglTr1dqTfycxy7uEA5WUsmLpIkkZwn581km0vs0m0AVLYNAElEGwHgiqFg1jqXL5J0gqSDp1Il4aXSdBY/mDb@SnI3kcTZWeJ574CpaV3Qph2@VP3VVyoImoTthB7OxMehWlClCgWce0xIr8be52o59/jwqX3ffWBwidbG5YaD88qkxjOUPHlnf/I1QsZQY0nSqiem9Xwwe6c0GoKyreL2SSVSBSWgrxQF@bLBpFmDBhRVCHn/S9/PT7fL8KzKCjyraiGjNhrKFqihifH7L37Pd2fk4uDTvUckiXOBf/vHP1JLf/vH/4YueU7O6fygmislABKdSrGUuLgYX1yAEjhnYYVEO3FtiVcbyCQpWqW0JQIvSGUNHB0pwUgK6nJJSSc8IREseC8WhFRKkdT0Vq4spyHkMtiiJqXKZXgMJ@mpF18s8OnEwbFZUJXd7R0o2U4ur9Y2oFqVaHcHEv22Da@S4BLlx68uCYEHvdEbDEyVuiQpaEfvBLL9TtiGO9TwO2GDvKo3cJ2aghtDhFO@W/h6OS7ASDYy0laSgK1NGs15bd7O0GljOhjycstuXSFGawNfUlz22rLhZ2x59GcY9JF6ePAYPhlbrz0@tZWWpF6P9js4ZS8IjQRrdR2DFBrAL1sS5HIrnOZlP0Fopd//0m@oavFv//hXLzuXnc9UVa1UKkVFTfzsZ9sTe@IZvcbPIOJRuBkYMJFu9pBZT5xTw/bEaMyBdnamjZ@oMu1orIKwXd/MIFbkEHWeS0xstMcYfDhygWMUBHRSc2AbPTpiwZ2hRk2rtcO23@qlKNgWAYMkS@05ut9PusZxoa3D7DV3oGcpDrKFm9Q222nugvsIg0A/I2Dz1biPFqjAYwQamaN3PGvijunLnSkaT2lnyV2IAil8hFubbQB0mgT9tgCSGPrqa1FZlj1KNapzk5HhebhRGqgj3EcQJdjJ25qRseZ6BoU0bdAVRASh@aQBvSak3Ya0LRahQ31TtPQMIEtY7lgkG8w47iPQLykVTFA7ibkNADWQKR8BAaAMqQCx2SbbJJcmF2YmU1vswjbH3TfwNUct3CaMw2iIrQdkiiLXEA68wHzEb8ciXwQ1DHIv5hkiYTjYCqw6GKAYnT6hQm8CO0w/GBXgOh9iDdGikbt3F7mq181emtASIf5Tc4xDuLQe7NV5BWShJX8HRCqoVJkMVvZHy2wHFM/Q7ALXCWxju1osKuHxcc5x8P9gpkWOvFJVNKCGBQjqi7UKHUgGkZHsrA51sl0nilpKkyjzOuRdp5mim8hEwxOt6R1R/SwMnEMOf5YIv8wEwuokPiwe8O19w7ocXUYE9wgYYRO6/6A/1JgwCL5Iz/aCRKF36Iexo1hQFNOi0H3TBVOYLvQKd1dL5ZQ0RlvsRkfzQV/pUvMEX6wqpPFGYyE0gbuGu30F6WxQ9VV3oEK9sWPT7cF8FE34ahtwBMgoSOCJ4xss2xP7HD@jFtQNjRzPEZQSLB3kfMwx3e6Mfn@exsUVU13X0E5D2mSJMRCJPuoRtUJSlNFsXDxgR@jSNBLNcBcsKKRx1zJGkKVnhkHfsfaqkjQAxW/SxTlp6bEJfDV8YEL3Y3vSfUZg6dw8NaUT3M9YcPr4KjZFDlhAV8Tmx9ZcgbE5sXrEcpxTYpmnBpvtSMW3WsMvOBSzYPxkgbKLEwhbRbVXzWVxIEzJMig4S3ArMWc5G4u7kZqlr99zykaqgzV6SXswE2rFMs40O0ZfelxywWCKN/M4urNcnaDxkIJnMRK50DLZJk1J3KUpmRaB9r1UmqP160EUjCniLNo4xSf4tOiNLdOnTm7sGmcEB0M47GNAaOqdIAvYiqG0H9EOgLY9aFm425vvVqHmMpATt5fSoekFAt4md0hO5RAQUkZQlgHAgVVfX8YOYRAVy@H5PagYkU4doVyB1jnqQRjuJhWwH8YPuRvddO@9BXuTjQAddjo0rTphzSJ8KMQesHUgP9Oib0BgEXK4IicbKT4DaDN8mmeoo/hXozNu56gsqZLrmLIEMQSkBixUVdBQ5NA9UhffO8MVGvc0j30UA7kemP78/FykGxtOXFM0PPwGmOfYmiWNByaow47kG6Nx8LVlU5fGId6FS2Cf/hPHw/HOFJXaeuXujN05ru/VgyWUqWTfS2LneIafuBqMztC@ggz3PcpQD0z6eTw9FazoZPyntrMXIf9Vkf@EcnKOSAhBNNPsLKtnAVm2q59m@@e9WhBwRhskIIdaNEJP3G7UDR9GXugyx/0IwvFRjkZBXeuUrjIATDybMVgkzUoYQs7Cx@B5bOLKa9s4J3uuq81SNDyN0MjAqRlVe8gMun0aAk7cMPyC7X1pTpuz9lL0aRQdOrVoVQ8I8hT2XDciZRuhYviUhU8hfMrCp4tEw2Sb0zZTydBrjsVBrscl5CEkopmFMHO2aegihGIGPZwoDAVCzpb8cKmpXqexQ3qzJ6jHesgYwBNjILiRkpovW81W2/aM8612RhoAs/OUEFDjgLrZpjQ970VupL51Zo0db8kLug@q3gT5Ri99GHAD4xUsY1RBlDEYvUzc6HEwClYaMYUgKDBgQD0MAlE12PNTZroW7bxLA4FxmvyCxixjzSAzbap9BUGBH6hLjPSMsHFE7Rgi9I@KBNmEEBK2HPbFx1A6vHAdgAlhBfqROhCRM5JsJ4GSV5oKkzU1WkmxXAlCmE0gO6qr9atFCcOhKppXgmLFnAf1H8/@xpfOfh/axercU4ZlHUaNizcVXC8OKkTQXChVSaMeq1fIgbSlWYYLPdcB00@D3hqS2ZJCM4Olg0Xwzk1fH6Zila@nWf3QV/t5m69GrDCr16GIszprlqxdhCRlBI@ieUG0WcgIQXwmQACHvDKaEUSbxqNN63UmOMh0TbTzWCanNJNTFoVBT9dksh1EA@vpMOxesHraoJ3iSnYe8CmsGwU1aMwTTzszcGHH68lojFZVmOZC5lAuCHgIVWzkM729MvVmLNMxoXUFATLiNQQ99vHoKndV4ClC9BTJKEbKUEaxp4ANmKwABqMiuMYxGyhiMmoDg8LPZ2g/AG2XzzQ5XqFTBfiT2clnQ8/wVK57ysuQyrKnnL3y@wfxbCNlYw00pn0och4FMrcYqUhsSBPPpRvMsw13zzmOvgxD7j8lLx7@v9193VYbybLmNfUUaQk3KlMqSdhgGxC2AGFrbww@/NjtAVpdSCWobiGpVcIg2/Q6MxfzAjP38wjzKucdztU8xUx8EZlVWUJgunuf2bPGaxlJVZmRkZGRmRGREZG1A3Xwtq62Djf@rj7tHqqPtZ0DxCe8P1zfbmwo@l/f2a9znFP67wONAObxgkdSfyvkzPcL5fIzxZA3@oOxeOAUNlx5vk9i9lvCFwv5ahxcvD6XH34vHK1JrToSNcOBJ@IkxiThQyMhHbVF4FgIa7NzGI5eFZU9DUiCgKR3QfJIJ6KyBITKRsTa2p@IBP4WyaSkk2n3XE8Uo/MAFyqdQW2Cg1MXF9m3MVm6WN0ITCAWCr4flUpwhbDtK0245N8fpuBBfe/dvkJozMbuzmbjoLG7s6@2dvfo5/tPjZ03RM/G/sFeY/0Qr7jgu93NxlZjo8YPBIGyrxCs8sslqY73oeCjOFOl9StkQ74GN/mVkUXzjtPrq6uA3eRiNXdJn9EoovX8S9ieW3GIl5S45vFkUoXZ2t6bD0flExX@BhnACEssoecOY076PFtWq9waTce1415Opj/ncCpWXJ6xF2OFRNs0fVnV4e@eMsBZzW1HtMpsQIvrzY2UBKnAIKQMaGroEcEGKKPSVdUv/ahXmJvzVhnkGrXW6vaR5EVaEzOb/oGqr40ytuIwxbQ2CaA4MW70sIpVVpIHxPf0YEE3OxpKAfU0eSAF1DN5MAp@DRvQrtSiLnE52r2EwUctyYNfLgZbLDip58mD9YDFqhcaJxk3HtJAnab3LlwMSH2Gaw1vrpw5XOK5UCXm8hFUqK5MjJDUbmJ5kt1ks2XrD5XM0XraQY5xbRiSuwvwlrgBmnTQGZHqXHV9dQD1Oexh9tCEOusGPTESpMot8556gXDRqvbCjXqtIeOp2nKPPTOgOh2rLB5JvU2p1w4fWo9qrt9qMdBWRE6Cbow030Ng/RYCfwYMASra60XQ4gz07LkIMP2OZuVC3CeOhJHgd7s8sXP7EqY@q4K2axR@ib58cTWRvbRKlFryGDsaoi9IOSybPUnTNMd5WeVrJ7AKts77g1EkY1jI9oAWzlDuxqDS1Ecg@HN1LdMa6DDZYq/fsxo9JS6@o9VTYsqHtMocL9JlsnylSfiJ86NeLJYpoBOc4hrYNGm@p2Ja20J1BgdIscza1wJAkXecdO34XcWk57yorm2uHxd//9k7KZXOZFmQbPrGLIf/cs0AdhL4oYhJj2TkkZlpGqgTX56itrZS6dUSs9wAq9L8ijoj9bq5krwTg/zt5/BLmHzOD799q0qtIlYmfXVDfF5IVzdPHZkmPa5zorSSZK2dhCyt9QXzxGOYyXr9Gj4IGIUVokgP6wgsBpnLC2hCyBJiend62aGVRQQzM9wJfFetsc6RXvABBwF7PEo/Fdar82tuKVW5lEXOglmiPQO54rqW4sb71S1wm/eDo/X74eBe3IudbA9/CNrmvdD@EG7F@bthybZkwXo42N/vASub258CS3337gYsm@RtaAmnJ8zpzeYTe/P9Lf58a@x47hEY7L2D/iAFarV22eviolGTLq0gFVwbTCoQ7R9s1vf2VI4dx5apLq178AVr62UQsB@Z64zY@b3Hi52fCE3mXyo8mScZm4/5d99knkq8O5YKLYN4mh7JYpFeZdMhlYpXPb2zsAjB51O8IBrKZbH7atag@EgDvjmqQPFLB83qoDO1m3nZfKLYPibRdPNENrZPufgMQvZuKjoajm1AttYcnOHsdfr4fRT5eNm0IwIWwuPQ4TZJ0rTfkJ6wj2vfqaDvZ0fwnmExQ4pjKBGw84Z2MI2UsxL2X2coZiQRwkUWtpZ1LRxr1EQ@njViDpvssA0EsIXql2Lzpxdmiecnq/aAuummV8huQSRkulT7tc0VVP3kZiW5y6qQ7pPVRCC359osY3NksDzBkYWGvXJ3occ4LViaXB4mm6LV9t6miv@YpmSXyLRkaD61M@YlQV5aXHz6PdiTvTDVi38Vtuwhk@vn6GJA@n0KMh7HfFJFnNvY8cz7lAHuIZ0cPpkJM1GRRJ0pe0qm77wZ2fgRLmIuIWSQXbB1TnAnWnXV9QRu06HLjmRD5yK3@mBN4aSjMmtuUf/m/uawIH@3vUd/vD2ZbCgE49oNzq3e9YdxmPqtWEE21iM4F2efhcNhj4vJif8FoBT4oP9edxT2RxGTsPQKL/nUze5JR5/fi2HaM7YGbkRx7vGr82BE65zFUqlXit3VrcZ2XT3hJBcdtj6YQ9bcMOdaa8@jqHcfArwGs10C2wd7uTyOl@k/4eAZkEQm9ncpMG3c7@LGFCGp@YhTSmvDqV5bK5Oj34lbQQ/hGF7ucaxy3g9U0QW71He3XCd7WZx2q83UJ@TiQa9Atbxc0c9xVXpGggKeuVkQMpp4bm1YOMs0B/c4gMZN7z5fTxpei/WMD/KDUuVFeemlw73reSPv4ujlifekVc0p2nyD3kV8Obxq/3rWP//cUV01@OX0ujX@8ptSi8@Qmkst/CCplypL1RKninmukLXrZZk5VyP4itNI4Zou37hAzqlUD195pPiyQcVK8zLOECe4VD25MFwIJ5RR9eJo6aTaq5ZXLo56JytwgxnNV0fzlfkCHvxAuyitMahZaB2NTrCn2lbXsPeZb93ju3D04aniw1N68i4YRv3t2s6bjDUOAgBMYPo0BOMhBnxnBudoOJ31e@FVQZvJPAWOdSAgOTN8bl6Bkymf8sMc044IMxoVj6TZ@Jr/jl1npuxfDkZ9fmMC98Fa6lv0zZkxB/1luRaxHR5FJryfr1qLr9MyBSoSydOxnDMUKyKuVeBd5FogjlCTl8PccS4Hrxsgqr0djk6c2A@D1jmQwCV23@SGvdVVvtKOWC322YpXcHFuzUeK5RN87dJX@hiw@wKaYMk95oNRh7qP3xV8kSdsoxrxSTIfITksKeINDkjUV/YA4PqrRAAh/IzIXL42cWrJiwRJ8a5h4wLCW7OK/yNaBOB4JIMyg84CtrRXTYHzWQrTCM1qMtHzGb5YUGhF/3QPihX@dasbSXlXijNJ5tF1/SsGLXlI@dUaPrpptYJVrWiqmcIWKWa@Sw1Yukg9ehfStBqrjbDbJaSFFjMpOfCVPeB0@/NJ@/ER2jxJkJf3xVvvi5n3vrwXpNJSPm3waaFlu1Au/zUtd6NyaTHvVltVxcKLTyPd8kkkScuu3Fc29kf9ZpQWXkuGUrgyebGaeVG03vw0ZfTlzaNMnYTBk/dH8l7z94Ie@QTLTNnX2fbx6egBwh@z/0xyqd@Luq8cfX2cfgM2yxE1lZLqfCOHMpOqqr2U9HJCEhzs/Dxt16oplPmKWXF4zuTWVl/nfC1kvCpMoiF@Prcm1pQ5YlGJ25xnwl2zSw@1w68fWSAYJhhNmZm7ZiqPdeWxBRalHplmxU/o1gSnrk1O8So8h77hj5nsWeRMufz0lzOC@bV0Xvz/sgTiRfdRbjqZsqsJDlTloe7UPbtI2vZ4EuL0RWLHsgInbYbipdiBGfxRsk7YC4VZKW7RPXmjKZ0WqBj2vWsI8fLG@d@lJ86bgGTsQTe8VjWoGQH7KTgZF9BRGONK4POQA1JwHXwXp44s8F2xk6HO3bewiOOWFKK1s/tOowNjMZf38E27bFIlX@0C8lUUh9aL@PLsDO4W8BHrX2FphcUlQghTbywGDZozTxfEETNUOPTlBbgbndlIyMjJ7Emui/UdfXWuI13tRPomG7anwxkRkZy0pS07zr9cRq1fN97gPPd5pfy0YpHssz4OLvtPn6UuCEQk82IBoduLlWeOY50Nt@RsuAiAntrGRv@BeDP8HPZ6oVOjHYMLxrjhOBx@Dtu@4@yFySEw4IKVcTIJT8X@5bAlxh0SugJiRvjRxZ4chxGH4RP7sxwXt/iszHNwaJWeNtNQf45w/XTizdvp43SYDyzgSCv0QKWLcEREeeKqLEp89qxxYdnlAoYoogYiAayziYQMvf4oatHIsCXL6RIoOQZJG@u1JzCh9lrdAO5z/jQEqCGLAgYBc5R0Hw6OPjT/Qzgo3TFzxh6YkSnR6tfnuULTPRxGtPqmBOZR4WoW7jTAB28b@2p/d@vgY22vruj7@73dD43N@qZa/8Rn3Dgo59wr6u3uNq0uyWm6nJrv0oNcbZ9q5viFU9v5pOo/vt@r7@@r3T3VePd@u0HQCPxebeegUd/3VGNnY/twk0/fCYLa2T1Q2413jQMqdrDrcaummpPWU7tb6l19b@Mt/aytN7YbB5@4xa3GwQ4aw6l@Tb2v7R00Ng63a3vq/eHe@939ukLHnM3G/sZ2rfGuvulT@9Smqn@o7xyo/be17e2Jju5@3KnvKXYSsHq5Xicsa@ukwqIl7udmY6@@cYAOpd82iHiE4Lan9t/XNxr4Uv@xTt2p7X3yNND9@r8cUiF6qTZr72pvqHNO4TtUoXHZONyrI7oIlNg/XN8/aBwcHtTVm93dTab1fn3vQ2Ojvr@inO3dfSbY4X7dozYOatw0wSBq0Xv6vn6432C6NXYOaM84fA9/B5cG@WMdt4Nv1KjqJhMYbhDoLRFpd@8ToIIOPACe@vi2Ts/3QFOmVg1UgEfFxoFdjBokIh7Y3VQ79TfbjTf1nY06Xu8CzMfGft2lAWvso0ADDhmfiHWo0UPuNcaJ8JKvxKyO4VyPh1M1tlRt80MDmOvSxAH7Dc0tTLaNt5rmPpKmWEaUqA@bQXBhG1Y6tx99DhHof9siM91Gk8QUbexu1mlH1rFgufTFIe06LyaCjex3tNMkL@lnJqijHZ5enjVxNTu8sJJqYvi4iM885Fl2keH12Lkn/lDbV7hCPt9sfqg1SdHdbzZd7yE1M2h8r4Y2g99XytV9RA4/aN4w/CwvC91XM4Ra@0EfdHpKkstwSaH@D7y5wqPIVaVSO9TV4N4KwMZ0FMuxyTmOUmhpZM965KRNm2TLBP@ONDtwxYIB77easJNSz6VQP6Y/vW/pD9kcrAe0Oou5q1SCEstoRF9C04w0wk7D/Ef77EYdbtKPw/DXs0LZbg46v3/W77eR9ULX4bIj0gPPCu53qp@GZxPVi5P1GVk@dtbJ6GKjd7MIk5w/a5IpPS7@kHtWwJ/miD9cg414RcNqyk2xsVobLQs/SHV4JHlKO3/fODqDEGS@d7UfGx@hzZUXnq1MPH@bPJe5hUQQyBlCG94R1zvhj7cnUoAmGHurE0ki7UNeKll1jL9JUviKCp6j0FXUhucP7dXnIe/rRBISZC@Drt0mduNhdG1jT@vwm73au/XDrS1aOoHtsxeLz5dWnCQw7UdPPj@hHc7awXF5A9rHSU7jV9Ys2SDBh2eKlWIpZX9m4FIJBZGzywwaP4QndOK3kfVkwkKG7sZI0NyDi14uBB1yil3UHzmGX6fOTM0AhUxXXfTmIrhmET8gWYl5QDuzdMc8atf4A9jJ9DdTPOmQZiDNYpzHhDiXtAte93KoxN4srNxwaAuK@DnDxxLomNCATV2VZR0axr80b1ujGIsrI@YrDzvXJCQeTWKhjF9FT2b2e/bE1wZgjq@jJz9qfqOvn3QIKAeEBvGoNtonMm4lNWGnTo3RutNHGvIJcigi7NC0tKpg5Xc1Ujz3tDk5cZ23ZgOjgjyi8DjOAl5JPO0nm4TSOfd6zlVfhVPh3g44K5pj9W/i3Gnd0VBWjIe9/m38tpXASsIAhGpXSRuOKfIp8fQ25MyQ6S/Rg@H/E2kyBf4qaZwEPaWWFSb7IEoyVKEVqa9MlOjKHDRYpxspNe1Hn1IwN/bAnCcd06c31xweChLo0RmbB584MLhTmEIAMDkMG/b8TVzSzgNSnV7nXF0d5yS91sWgoPReYbaKW3CLSycei12eOVvBD1e5YmuyGtymquq1KG6nPOtJZZpQ5dXjOCfgXOMhX3rCBpBkwjOXnovX6iRnlfUsM@uADkayNpx2ElNEYunNnad2T5QVRJ5Z@/XJlyEUgV4DPrf7yckk@0rcc7MxyXKV8AHHiSIjE9RkbD46qPOUHTG7IeA8brMxBPkmR1fYILoCnYNZU2iq8JgdRdBI6nWYRuJiuXV9Ii1vq1cJ9myZBIcm2B/2JG9YKFYtU8KXuGGNYQ9@hsQzg0HY89W7YEwodx/WbWGx0pP9vgffRTQmZgldH7k1W/3@kETHAP0mHL1o7PrqozY6hL34cqgjfGk/i4baImGEfmoGYpNo77zNSD4uRi2OSG6ALwvzB3fpIoSHKIOLrotLqkDMa3h0zRgdo@v5iiqspm9WiSYcuM9EXFVLuPaESwlBdVB9yBSM4kS5YJ9NbgfnDsn0u@oPf8XeDxGo1w7bSey@BZJtgTJIjR5HQbdG0vVBP2aLBg0FLCAJJSpiSEscVWmPfq7ZSfs15dL4cUT3c0/@eDsJkxpvKWooZVzdOjHfUpEGE1Ra0MHzSTh9ZWGRUZmmcN3cqYxxPH322FrljnvJkrIsQkT1sREd8U3WzeTbJ3zTRv7q4xizh57gjFuLoEAYMivOVW@vc4wffAo@RuGwbdtESZJpBwOY31j16feYF43pUAfGtoJRHI5JA2iVousSw2gW/tY/7zU3@t3gLOpHAelpSJl1LSsevo75KwbsbNi/ijltrNxqYBVqj9PvfGKtAxXxOzmXXLGC1@JROCjYbgqj4biGxOLQYjg0E4eoyX7F/D2YjCJM6jxbTCulDirAw2d/vIq7cmfdp5VpleVEHwD0Arc24UHBoY8h8lhUTUv9QWHCsw8FTu8rYOF4qooqcO/w2Mtg/JJIxMcwGYwNMrfcEuxOQDO7E@Oj9rXX5ijdYX9E69ZmiFykcYEfewGu1KJV5BU8BZZV5UXZqiqnKNeI1MWX8d3kXnj@T8aeEPgL6FeeTuOWaYzAS1xHzwZak1mZ0HH4hAu7B0a8RvNKTKtYdEa7UDcDtHk9CTX7enwXNdjzh4QiHYh6iysxIwuk@CC7eaFJS05z7GJTmVNzLgd/QgSpjQrluxk2/J7/LE9@HOKK5QwL04aGXLCQvotULaISLumZcK@1UZasI9@fMQsLDx21CQJWp7mcWbdXFXJGcuEIlEj2Vxxr9Ye0GOcmqKddPebiUX8w90Dq3bl2TI1dnEbrlut@1xFYmK1Km@WTNpO2OsbX8Yozic8E02Qpxp5mxENQX/l7wuaTRLyuNjHfqs3xd@hwF81Sv6lkU0nGuy1zH5viZ3j0mo0mmVKMO8L4V5LnR03qePPuFUTDFPWqyStGE0tGcyxfLVATZEqo9HAKMfdp3Cfo0SbKod020c4enzuJOukkZ5ICmFeZMHDQE6mNELRJ69KgA@eLgmvOp5JFKhE4r70xH@VViqdIw4EXAhBScVhM7VBiwU0Ha4KPOH9Wp9CEt1AFKxF9W7M9HJK0WAnBOG@VNu5oj4fmuFg5WRFI1wkk0iq41H2Q9CMUO2peM5RbpKApPoUUSY9urU3nD@/VX@0LlSMIUptfa0/fsofOuGqesKE/9qvmNWTgtCldMzOjshOhyUsDzQXSUs66oairkP6ioXA8vBv0NCIFQh4X8DGvayDhzVI5oTaqXLfHKOJqcstsc3FhDVdJGUp@g/x6Koqoy4orAQgFY6pfrRAEBP4z9jgU6IadUYbzMojqMaKK1QqmJT3kvAGpn@eU9yCqLvBs0SpRnlbipQ2jOBUICRbTy6SIkMwyvUgKhTa6qbhYJZ5P709aggRiw/tCcRoKPSpZGiYjJwTke4nKbrqiHFWUV9YczC@fLbqZlwl/89uXZettefIt0SfB8KhYmXz7opx5m2l2YSFbNVOT6OHarWZeEilcG@FkVfhr/zg0xU4KlPiEWkpGRsrQ/tm4N4q0TNLb/F9itcpB2UbGMPDsyHCjfjUlCWEmbdH9KYrUHB8ZILvRX@6t8Uw1mOhsWnPHPU6eJMZdUQhZYs1hq0e3oOmyNwUMJyZBgdFp@x314WBry1aCET2sHY0uwuFiuVwGE5/a6aGMbzVMSVG/lC1d6lx2u6XB1d@GH05LvPbjFstu3F82GnRIQ0KTIvb7wzPJnQYcqChKF3UgK3T9y07HTlKGE0oMHg2blNTZEBRvQFHi9PLhQJImb6Ub7M/oIPr3s0pm31UggqaGYo6hqDZcgj/nzOkZkQcPOvDPTk6qGBgWZuPNRPuWW137ih0Euf94sDjBh/s1dU/OvQ273b6nPuLiGWQKmLmZrLC1ZVcoSxGcMHJ07yXSY8ckk4Wfo64VV4wiNq8DnNmYTCY2kzkJ2aP2wrP69aCQO/opR9sKdXke3ZxHBhdP5c5yrk6n9ACwwoeE9oNKXwSDQovpNFmYtno9g9NvhNHTijdV98kUcdkmpmn2/dIg6nR0fU7WQF13WRYw2Z54eLkndxRPiJs7vq50QMOywNA4EQN3H1YDoWb/vGXx86jTediqyImyZGD/0IoouQL/2oLIZwA8A/X0I3oiY@bfizSttyYSioiAg3R2t9cdVGiiguM8blV/uyrUajU1O5ifV7XaOn3B5Q3rNbWJB@vrahOZ8fH7h@rC4uKKrLmb7ld6uG4e3qh1gsEWzvnW@XCTftK7KuLG4K2NIZ4tVWe9ldlmdXVtJS4d1dYR1k/f/v0//9d//y//rVTTP/4Hfqzzj6OfkkK@75dmW19nf7hZwe@jzZO52dOj2cHJ3NkKuIzIULsc9RujYpC6j/rDUycvu4D1lP1IjZ7N2Wd0VWVSXl8Ew19pdVlW@VZcyuunseRW5TU23wqt5yHiKE9JhTdpuSZVeQdpjy@CMczxNDqtEA54tN8QJQkX@IFKfTlbMYZ7pINJCiSnKnmdiYdl1s8hYlrSTAqIxaUdqxj14rAHC/hnlnmle44T0Gc0amr@Lf2k72J@clxQT8rqiaee5HL8gXuZnxy7s6UI0blSLLmxOT1agJuhiiMW9Fh/4GyUE@R2nFlOaglIJk0FF5YoOC/R/jhYRlISx2fODG4nUGIi4UMmVMl/ne3d0LB8pRI3uUyoDQsKTa3FcGPWiUoyvhCBglgcAdKWL4Qgy31qEid9HJGMbyXzRI@1w/k2GTDIuvdmi@c9HtBeNNvTPs8ZXQqJQNl9Xp5ib1yRYGhGG2@k/RQBPlARdbLMkYRz@TlHvLytXnI3JQrb7p9mPvF1GIcj45sulX5XFhOIN7dNuNmejmvRjtxyvKJyUXK8YjWVm/T9Vo5V5eKyO4oGOlyBW8eE@pq0diMzCSPKgASOZMVdvj3D2FBgMkVNDIukkx2rdh9dl5mgb9XDdHB9OTmyiFD6qUBz@9vE3HZLHCVi2EF4gJFKXPk6QdSNddYVuZ7vLBieIn8238KpopGcm7E9D3clTGDc7yRI@wyZXc7T@UxdyQ@GwdlF4Kn8Tv9gGIwbtG2R5DNq@S71ECmYgAQmn256WvcMwtIjPSRMkaQr7DmEjLzdsU4gLGObS2JOMKRmKui0K5gEGXZiSobfMmM1QceUq//AINgo31q8k9NIvcTyygtPIw0pZ4fN8DS7NXUc04I9d5KJk3ME1WRmGl7QlS6x0V7wwS@t5F3kCNBt53QUoA5FWHqJ9rE7nYW9ILM5DbqOCfQvrSjZFzGfOVm7eCM5GsrzSpoTGliRHPlTNguE7E0mnZEzUyjMHMc64XHe3kcgPPuJL34pUFGSoplT/HJkiDrsRbJYTuxQkdCemNBXDfb8JwidbnBG@I2vgjFY8ThfePWo5B79dNw7eVI47n07/uIyJnpJNrtsUeX1YbZZsfRcoZ2x5GV@Gq@0mEjACZyOe9kCxz0lMSwWCQiRUuHop9LJtxIhdJx33Sel47wQJDNkwKR0f3slgC/dQjOfxaKUd2bcJ64Z/MKriqtob@VPjKE8cOWTsDBKJZvpSc8ZdggUx@nyfc9Q7EovFsrPFirPSBM6C6@Lw/AS@20xvjwNr0mUiKHO0tZz/CXDDRlC3FzHwQo9vKZ@Rmc93PjJIxrrICW9hOppzu04CVtRHV94gsoTlQsgAUJc3KRMgMNHKPyeIpYzZTkXlLgOWtxXwP4Z9y/QThBjXZuMDhGOhJeB@IiwCbUIyJrx7uRQ10yXOY5z8tXGeUiDDCA0vKW8tVv0@r2iFtZcf24FQjSiZrq4r3Fyjt6aopkZOquFqblHqrL26vm//ffd3/Kj/NpC6eOQPkf53/JLL/Lylb7Qr6fm1@f8Wn4VxZZu8uMS6cD09fm//U@qv/Y3goM341X6s7ZoYC2N82vFKlf5ll9boi@VhQVq93/9679SH2ZFY8NtBbNNTzFiK4YiG0GPeZfeqwZ6KWrpXLqscGAWYIiHIenm9AOOUdcLL8pspstrr4rPoc58ZfxR9BbPjlkjdhUSS4bxpyDJSCpU0UBRQBoXio6yfDeM2waYN0VT/fzYX4pJA/hZu3MkTSauG49juAzNilpEA1iQFkmfly9r5Ve5xL1jOWd8SlaMCAnVTq@1L56uEDu874ejqJX1kjDT9aIVXIWnPvjQD9uXpFP14m7/l2HpM7HkRWXhRakD436J/bhLA4ZUHIz9LyQI6gzzpBiy06mnhjQC/Quk8PI47zwJ9FvJmZTJuE5S9iBsiQ0re2sHFZEYP0@Oh9EdPxWlC/yXBHjkltep0q1swsc9qrm7t6xy80lBKcc6rwts3rNzrE6BURRvWL6VkAQY7gOsg6Y/fm14xkFIXGtIEKSIH7TbzUC/KzgzOZNM2HNmzsPuoJpj3zDqzfCSXYs1/UXMvBNKMYIFoVjkhQ6wLsJRQCp6NcdPoI@nLSBNij5rTVLFpWTt6LJaq29XtzhY9e6mr6TpKxpRSAlpOwnPWNnYlF1M1pYqTJXDsIkjtakNU2uxudZk6PMHMIhlWBodhCXo7nAEJFEt7Y72KrOHzWNdmHjkKpSYPTEtyt0uTj4NfvRMCYmghuyEdn1pjBaInX4vXIaHMv3elwiIqknEH/Ucyec38drk99BguA@7g7CXSVsnyUdlW@rRfsgCB2IpFZFA55W1fbAd2T0S0EmKreSShhwMLzkXLNVZZmWLC5rhWOaLUkxKqFxO7FRHLZVcwNDR9ztwCgU8yJUrC0@fLS49f/ESeYBndG@ng0ElH1rA4DwgGCxRF0jJxvNqNTeXk0e4pOV2k4A@DSwO4ODWdeUyVvL1UbVS1sDKOYZ1xZeNSHVtrmSQKcRh6GNHIB2lMMwVCq@Wj9Cxk@O2@43@E3@b/IDMcCYdbSCkt8bhfZqZyrmQhANVXpg5KU4BdyXTFiJv7LJhv7OHbBMhfF2F7amhbWSAGJ0P@5dn5zZ3@Dq11QFNGCL4aDheZg3qTThKE4xZWEEW1QaHhhV9UTXwjm73AE652BIg8wlwmmY6b2WgPU0xO@ZoE0JmTUSs4gjRch212Zm5s9dX9Z3NScT07Tacv1Xg@rZnKwl3nMkMCWRwm4XV3QOirs52waGkek3yMlmVeYEro1yFw@EDxEq3cFWLRRWzVrPcMCrcR5YK82Ka2jStSuMIvKbArJS/T0oT12p6AYKYhVBbk5JFzEvOc2ySpTjZg4x5Cl7OLVs@ou@iOOYEc7qxnKs9SrkQDWQspxLTAMJuU85JR8rLGFH@WuerSWS0ke5coqJhGtBuyImmGk4tGXW0qYCjxiVbfEIL9L@xs@GpzTr92fq46UFQXq/9Hf1OLkG5G9@KxreyrBpbZgjsbLHscwufqd8QokTMUtYJY1MEsfiyYQP1kqwB9caWpr1M6qPM3D5JuQLsGmgh3FhH9SRBohe2gcxo5T1JxcHhOvxsWYxXt1eaJKWKnhZi4rp/Yls0mUlbTSAJKR8AYmESRJKoJeX2mZThxQOdJe9A6y6GsRtb03k6w7KiUJHYvlUismd59k7K3McWC5otFpYxjvfxBfPtvbxxGnb6OhYtYY7v8MajP8cbxYczR/H/C@ao/3O446nmjqfLWHuEO5K04RzRyRcV9adwzOmY9@BmOzqLYB/qWD/RibJnAeAFDxgihpReVsro2x3LiSpMfzE/uR/BSWhhccn5k51/pjv/bBlrLn/dDP9f7XzxH9z5Rd35xWXsNVNGXot2Vrr1f0yPU5GwkH0wdXgh7kox98/2dEn3dGkZu@mUYf6/3tPif1BPn@uePl9GxgQ5cJD09fdzs0gitf2NRiN1t/DNrZIF3PQ0nStd6F7tao6Uh073Mj6vQlpXfxr/Fxr/F1iN@NseyBpYMcqJLi/qqQTLi2TJVg6FICvpifTXZEa3@qs3rFQf0RuULNJs2BpqRYUEck9epqdNfio/pqtvsvk8FGdZ2zn/oSRctRRo0QgrbjrFRfLlwuZSvRlhZORAVhsHe9vz/0nIcBH8qqPQCHkM7VXY7ZqdxFbBDpKsU7ozVncAe1/rHBlW0eRkZEc62jthl5m7VzVObDGxL05XEuSoTa7ARJZI@2YBNhkRbXxd32hVcM016oU8ob5Loeld1j3@U1z6UnPpy2W1pxWDu0gVaIOf5sVUT1tYXLxvD5BaPj4wAcselb9nVv0f)

Compile with

```c
#define _ENABLE_DEBUGGING 0
#define _ENABLE_STACK 1
#define _ENABLE_EXTENSIONS 0
```

Coordinates in the interpreter are `unsigned char`, so it can only exit on a line that is shorter than 256 bytes
(otherwise `x` wraps).

Minimum is separated from regular Minimal-2D using `V` and `!` instructions:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.V>!/D<----.
                                                         R---.+++.
```

Answer (score 1):

## 415. [Hyeo-ung](https://gist.github.com/xnuk/d9f883ede568d97caa158255e4b4d069) ([rshyeong](https://github.com/tirr-c/hyeong-rs)), 18044 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,

















































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000';d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlpstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let r,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?/<p>3r=0+@#posHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyckCa^ x._  \
 ; ;:
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({102f5585-5c3e-4da5-ad0b-57c4c4f66a96}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKpIisSTb1KkpFKpbul2PdQq1b3Xl2SxQBAkUQIBFgBKZEms6O6Z7XWPPTOenm5Pu/247fZ6tr2eiPFOzKzbO/ZMhL0fJxzzyT@g/NjYsB3uf9B7TiYAghIp1W3bG44FCSCRefJk5smTJ8/JTCS6mjf8yU8SeJAjx5oNLMcnvuH5pOeaZ4YrknszsquZXkHNcRxC7bmDyciwfa/KJYhCiKXZg4k2MEjftHzDzRLPMEjXsJxzCFcJ2Z7YE8/oNeApR4htnJNDWzd7gIH4zqlhm28MF8LyhNw3rMvRpU90ZzTS7J5Hxq5p@zS0QMiRBg/9iX5KtK7nu5rum44NQcWlJEoEouunFI5GHrsGQ1Em5LHjegZgdXTD8xz0rICn5prOo70nH16BV2TyoQYZGVvG9EqSikI@MQ23dzWGSj4@efDgqm@OfFlwbPLgepaUPNmb@M6hfxV/gewNDFsjqlgR1auBRSCgb1hluSxfDSpBHRq@qV9Np0z2@n3TNshjKPhSIIQ@MF2obi2oVqJrNlQfVu4WMUZjf0YExhCaZUWV7RHNIxNvolkUzp6MuoYbAnq@5vqmPSDnpj8k/tD0ongU2htruiH0DMscmb7RI5YJkZx@gAVQ2z1yaszOHRd4IMDp2NYMIhq62TcxSpgPQIhHyh8aDM9ImwEH2D5wC9GIB9mwjBBbmksA/H2jOxkQZ@KPJz6BvPVMT@tagLQ7Iz2jr00sP0u6EAY1QP3Ph4YdcDegEwHFicNy9WpCs2YsGoHW6xEZGBvycWoQE6hGs1UluRz4E8cFqgFUmKMAGWV0VkZjChUKVdR3qqQgyxB@EPlgbjXLc4LMLGcNA21ovLTOEO@R6wxcbQTU6BmUph8fHhFPd1x4ghNhWQO7CY2u@WR7myQPntxPkkZULaLb5aIqqpMLqIJEGEjONGsCHBKvCQfqx41ic1hlyY1klSSBLKpM8nmSh3ZcJmoBiKTIFXCAQFBzCpxFopZJXoHmVSA5AM6ppWQW0@u72sC0DIZtgNhK2DoATIWrnCc5YPxcMcegB47VZ6A6TbhEcmVSLJFSgZTgWiEVFVLGZPJEqRTgLMIJGCuQLUCk5iCTssqQLdoB8C3y3j7payPTmgUp0CR0UlBICbBC/hXArpYBC9xzOTxzcJYR2/IRx@0PgfpD7QzQC5Z5iqLLiKQXVqkEN2lrS6IiE2UyS94bYvJASiBioUxKkHwRKJKHLACl1TIkX5BZQbyhYVlBtKGH0WhuSzKckPMS0KIMtSEDTWUkaglOeAbhqIIUVEHkqSDFVJA8qgruHCYBcEUIK0LVFvMsmaHmnUJCLB21RysARD6gUZDiKPEUJBJggFojQGqo9jwwRg4Zo5AjkH/IS6lIQOiVFVLOk3KJAD0rMoH6USBfyDUKCFsF8qMgMuADBRhBgTwpQG0FkCq5AuFixFZyGA5xcxAXSKPkIU4e3FBxShFPiAfcoUCSCqSpqpUFU0Le1AKUt5Cj3KoWoXZLEAZ0UyGvKrCUCrlVyxCOcctAwzIyM7AvI4SGdIBaQfYHXgRiFCA/FC/AglstBcyrWeOh1kXRzmJ2@xi1iM2iiGSEqDIWD@55pCZkRQY02Bog@ypwQI62Hrjno@QtBZA0Eb3RM6nAtrCPUCIKlbKUIV9pY39BNqVIczSe@cPIT2V@DghSE4ShMdD0WRQIrTAbBS58izn0VansXSCS8@jrgaR1Jp61QBI58ipNyjgzrYVfmfr1DK3XN73h20Ve8zSRrqH5tnm6SKVQyMaIqsUCihiw5FXKxWF9U4DuazBE16Isaglhxk5UQUtZVhSava7Rn9gDQ6iUY/mjIf7E9aGjWaRZYd6uORhAH73Ao2RpMWnHufAu0BxauZzPRZ5IXUzTNaE7v0v0IWgfUWCF4a9UFjhyKuKYaV3s5QVQ06BXqGA/1jenpHtXp73IIoM5Sid9aI5D4Opa4Fjl0kSm5WKMNyjl3pTlSDzj0RZfOaadSpJkmptz0Pcw1TPec0MH9wn2WtgPI@tCP@tQLWIhPlN22FOmgWjLnT70whbqQl1D17BHxv7JoP1riMf0RQKJgM5oOGeo19JOcikZj3akXRfVWNB6eobrEoQF3dfL0i7Xm3Q94/UE9apFvvrQhxvQ1fc104oyQPsRzacKAdyTHqQ3W85233VGtLMZYZdqOc54jfoCHfg5InronBuLrC/6d208tkCLAn@DKXGQmXONKuRUe4@nyjIEkTAeVDggpEmB9mG6hk5pHxQdYudAT1nOYpWojbs5xHIvpl7loLGA6uFhHHtiWVXQewyd5BpSzziT0IepYMuqF@YhVMpAtQpQdDVQrDHnNBcRpruqSNW9k7BmPWe0XDTWvx5GRR@aqChZ59oMaq8PXasx1Uag/hPUsaHlkhFwDKtBrAmwOLBYh6Tn2Ek/wnLuglILhY5KQhVnpIlvjgwwjxyIgjWep5nG3p3mrDsDVqbUyovUHmI5uUIokbtKKOaRj3mwxgLqX2@iI9UwbdOmHATqkoc6vwuikvlxvktaLQ1OF/S7cWACiuhAwGeYtZjB4LHWHmjiOsWIOqthe2CDeCIx0UADzh84fWC2cxPKDgILoi5w65QISILIayrqIkdJjgw0OrWISfTxmIA/dErAng/kMqikziuTvIFAawgmhT5x3RmZjqEmzBFA@brT7wP3vjHGQ0BBRj2iz3RonlDJlHu8oa2NuZ5DxYw@Xi7s4mnTABgbTZX9o58lAwOID2psHy1MZPxFMcZjWhBKEM1mKq6tAb2wIPp4RonDJRYx@o4jon/PMTzKMo57GgkATMwzBrSBQGvrL0TSCFV24FWbmho9kD9BI0P8mCC3sjCYVMALHxo2NCAdeBOaPlQi1uwe6YMtHlNk0frQdN0Y@wG3OFSomXbMCnj6AK0A6isEyERvyG3uku0rvAOgEf/ENFq0ijDr48A40VDiBga/QNWPyBBl8sWaXUseIM6upM6/RJilHLzk1@RhTBsGmkRUVEx8FCgoI019iBLRR5lDtW5oc@7kevHBL568OyJCP0obc6OA8OFEKfLCfKzHIcBpXUckji3E1VjyQNAlj1tQa95oBWYnyqTVi/uKkiaCaLwN6cixnRVYgZgRXgRZDqF1QZnxGcoOzYqYkTYXb6mOUGwvxqCwO4OedDx2XGgZTPTM6PgCrbIYdwVmeSrqMdIiubfcwULHkcRu38e@ECKMLQ14AZsYtlSwrzSQFyDKmNkMks9hKcYyTFs9xRXk75x2AIyZoEe1bQNNNM2dMSRQPOikIaEZMV0XhOEZdhWsJwq7FJHyKfQMWq@H8hXJQdv91cRF5Oj9SdecXrXNdfQUX3ncmeaSPprlLqge0IhSyb6XTNeoP40ZC@IlZ@xLNCq78gBIgUSo8lQfLH3oKh6AoHk2s/UUv9TE@CzhJ36/zKfBgRGZpkY@AoPhau7QiECmGZ1Cu6ZPNTKATlwQ4CqgH80JBkgiBmguaBvQCMHWrFR6XY1cgvRwiTDdZwZJaJgoYj5Ky7B7UVoBITAv8fKKLAnP1alDiPVtWAIEpyWnncQSAd@TEjQiDx6SFPSw6EF1PhZGtRvmObHp0B1JMYUkTS4iFRg6gBTNjAkqiKmbfidQWu7eDdWXjXodmA10KhCbvXTcrg3HOEWQ1AAsUp0kSET0nWc@to1UGsqLwHOWG1CegFPrDXLhD11ocfR5zgEQkJWzkZNDwgb1/MQ8nfSuVrSNngjEY6sD1cnUfb7GgQrAWkP9Jqoml6gKtm8SqYrMi/Ep6mvMS32xQvkAzDU8VILrQVZiNZzCHAS8upJELGrgt2Do/ZluBSoBc0FjZ9KoC9k/DYa3IkGUDXSCsNFea6kMCTYHhocc7Z08rAdtkQVKXdOuLnlYjq5Z1HsTwfkw7qPDe8d7xz/bWYHDMrvVqx6SmS8XsaudTIWBPZHyolrdjONYIL7fuRk3RlyG4bkgmAjONKYqzXToXKYhOZ8ef/kqSUATQnLQFMCN5xWVhsGA0sV1NW94pRMmg0wGkoyihLBEOCQhzsiBWcdwLczP0eTNG6y8q5kaB/6YM2uiMQShp3Roh/FEDLyigIVB3T7rEWlc0EVNG@cmFq44ZJifD1F3vpoZqlDHWObDpw8OjusUbTC6JlAQyfNBl9Lcngg8b03AEF8FA@IPXDrJiIuMo1ZN87qSwLq@ROBF3ZI1@AEBWjyiQwRrFBbNG0Le96@WjfoKesQB9JliuKpXxvUh/YtmNJYP7OJ0NHxX9aI0YNFZRV4re6wodLnb0gsFo5SvxLstfZFmL46UThVAPxDqjS4EnXoC@ogLLTJQq4PsP3t0LeMeVSLBFBDCnHkWEWlansWh9SKYJOlJ@2CnOZYhfkIlHk/4tCQlw9kCUfeoCRqDP5iafkpOs7uSBlhIfW/vUL0fAgcD13Q8gxoNaJFjz@T2cRpQ94BHbMdyBg7ZgjhMOwwTBLVpbTH3Bo59rYY09MSiJnAmEeQvDt9oY@hrzDfUfKSx4kYrm5PUbO8cpLRSzCGRKIUoKonCi6@0Mw3ItSj3s8PPDqATUQqyHLllegAJYnEoudClx3ypBxEgITHIz8oCRjOM11p7GCDEpviw0IGgiyLuLYJXelKJKUor4Vdm6SPnGsVfObMrrAU@jLXAESPZ4ZOjR4dPDh7vfdry1UJh6TkvV4pAOEivC7qQOGR0w9a6xZomFgvRJaBtuNi8QApMwEAJ55AmnguCW0QQkWVgDdewudnUR87QTnrpq4U5x1Dhla0zFnqMjY@BBhHB0O5ZaIy4bFIb@3Pkn6Hvj72qJEErH066Ihit0ivdsbSBRONBx2BZkoKmy@FTHN3wVsWAzHgzg8VgQ1ygOszoOKJmjRwwXujUOIoGkmLo6diVZQ6GYAvj/LnhpsWIg2lppB5YCGArS1HZqACmT0Db4B7WE89Y@wNFLTO@VmQ1L/Eh2FLzB9iNvgGmUwp6KyBF@sojad1t3SUzkNKI6SqSBBG36CCHR7AvsAgoknTsFO38kDhUWuCoKcoKSqPXExzTBSklFeR8SSkWJDDLwEwDnVXAkTdhpPn6UPAdAfAJTp@OG8S4sO/pmt0XtwJHmFnQ@@5AUXPNF62W3QYFvXWX5g1no5uzdlNpp2vkepStAD5dA@5dKh7ybugBvEudwJr0TtbIs552XZz1NNq6ekTyR@OgzxHG5PEeKFJvHJDXPSPe9jCCFA@UtpZgJQR@K60YELIwKocXpJQEDQp6WmA9CfMlgNKL6iFwDsitWASyGM2IFKaZPwT5kSOpfepKX9dw0TsXSI3lrODQsDiegcijQCi0hRxmKAygCY4ZBsxKEkwg1HgwPMmywFaixEQZ2v3Y9Ewn6dHJGlStcNjWG0M90lFvHTsKDwcqfeigo8aHHQXwF/YT5NxI4oC@5rFhU4gULD4I44O5GGGg0wPR0LgdrcUAPqSx6AgBCC9gbRy/HS6GO3HcAZgdEqR5wvEPUGJsOo0xgEJCZFaQPVYQlhL1WS7Sqe2c24ita5Cy0DV9NuvgTFychDd78bIBeE5lMICNFi7WtdDZ@q6hs@FeFpmWAuxQjYyMkYOjGaDgUWlk0CJobKYfzVEPh86hZcsCTl0CfoHs7oMg1Q02ZCWM0I4Drj4gSd@V9oTPJE14Aw3qBvUOCx@r4qDST0ICLK@7oAM1wSAsVZCcEQX6hA75YOC9UOMOWAs5i9fqztiwr5qdzChNpWt0fUQyyWajLpIbGxvJarKRzIJrB1zb6NpBVwZcO9QlUBfCieiiMbLUhaFNGgP92sl5M8Q8TbeRB6aovLwxxymtWa3m2lmtqQR3Fe9pqAqgPEALeAM8yXS9js50mm@c4@QRmBCxsu8j7zzTXXMckOAj0EnYc7x58UHzco0amsc3U2RUd8FuNVDLTbnJVlNutVsXrV6mNU9mMXa6ptXBRAX56adG4sB1JmPQHZv5qgDiNd3MVdu1bj0pJ7dSqbJgQUJaOn2nnM5ojNappAE8lWq1kkDSgDpNfehSfNOsmk5HhIJ89E0wdCwrlRQvypB@N91OZ5IQN53MQs9QTyaBLnTm06OFxkEJxkQPzCmQEhom9LLxyQ0qo@ksGTbXz4zxcObGAaKBP1D0cRB/sYgG1xphRxIX1G9Y/LhOuTTYEKreDA70axw/RJVtPGMdDMdy2pKWlmyFXf@Z0B85viZ9LILdJsZ67ORGUhIE6IxpCMNEi/3Y9LAJa7bhTLz4YOfKMVhMHXxPhhMQluGiuixwlTnmDH3okOTmLmAn0cQTCn6cQxPYTFyIoKeLcKIQRcUIZ21AwaErnUyQi3SNGB0YUmgmmOgJpwcKxfFrMUqtRuMQGRMyB7bjGgKQBGJwdFkXXT3INcIJ8kM6@Hat@wlCaa@KXZlpgER8YDkapS0T17GJqfEoFt8eYJRjo8dZID/6IB5FVheu0ZO2ODpd7LhD6CGgNCiJ1ai2RkGA5HjjnuhPISqXwj4/HsgMTNB7z0lPVdWiXuhXwzDkCiD2ECoJDWMbrOwwSFAgMB1U8gEbmQqHCZ48vX/Ahm9of489PA7ldUZObwKqbWC6HRv2IEsOgJ9M2xmZQIYw/ptT69hxfDbQAA/rBoeY3W6OJpZGh52ujgzdGE93uo5FR6NuirqAn7ieZmlsHCwM3fv4MZgbz0@e1cVqDEjSzkY3po1DoauTZfQ8jE9@0onfcIbKY4zJbxZ47LfC9akoZoKAEgaETQenawL/MvqPcDUqqOXBgAV9jDwDwAoFxBWquOIu8LxQ5Dn6rzX3IjiFwjEddZGrC0Wl/md@v7/knaPepwKKIGvhnafebKXqkjkaz1KBAeGy1SWYOKIihYlWr66FK1E4tpwGOHsRUKYBGl3LKuDUiRhNcT6O1kQMDSuc4zwGvQXn8aDrt1C7AusJbQW2xNQAVX@M0zVUgOMkINFBG/au6bLQ5MYCg@YSG7QZQRcnoWLDbUokGISv0YZkO8HkqceEq@Nm2fjOdoNNuqNx5zK7UmLTA5sdQLHdqIXr/9aBYUrJZARGsdK8QQxaTLrO4FpRo1UjHh3152iUGudJYNdMVVloTUsH7cuk5FEy9Anfak3vyOqnYCDhYs7Nu9LAqNElV2voVQtDkoEm250RAfQ@hGIj6PoQpA3JTJdJCfUzsfuO1RPYdB2wE2GGHlZQsGYiWmQarCU2TDdcX0oX@LKoKGVjS1Ov4b1SpY3rALHFrBEiaFwX5PI0e3ZJmtDxnYne2DL9NpmLvtMZBgu37KvLXpkm6rrazOOCJTd1snf84cdNuc0wcCMNp@DKrBan4eppUJ9BXcJ17@DChUO@6VN9gC6MMLG8igiZmtLZGsg@4GAJ1EiUUFAizPqlcbkoS98AkzllYM692ShLjPRc7Fua7xs24zk2D7qe3GzCKkimTpPfCWY/qkSmU0Sgn5oYBlmskWcn9w@Oj0XgXC@VPMCppCo0R00fgpqyrtAhJeOFr5I7vSS5g3HSOH7AQVMDG6QTxAemrgHTgxUCqaNkGRhuCjzTOAukgzedeKMRmZ4WEAiXf@k@pVGELGWkoUwUWXVl/p/bzOAK8lkFjs9QSgK5U3erQFszLU5s87XoQXdDtVcACUxW6DXqmykqyjaVdLC@b4Rz2GBnUdURStBsEuENiDoA5km7XWOLEQAWzTB3gNTleVoVdJF9XQmrvg7eoNhQDEH0@lvyoikLlXZmcxUqutYtWB/Pyh/DixiWUXvGymQ3U7S9X2vILA9sUpKJ7@fUqL7ytkiVbDIHzwa/KXi4fosKHbrca3nZ1vKiMGhkKEromBAWJBQJieDthYBnaTiV/GD5YDTqkUqTi4joKpKcXF5SGpJNlVAagkshrDLmoQ0KgumRA6V5FLy5ENcRaGsNVrRgm21xfGhsLU8ZYwhT5KWzKzqqcMbH4zEd0bRPHTrxFLk6sqgUUC@MYo9OresxcU0svSyBRnlgsOq63Hmjbp9eVgDQ@ZdgZp960JH9QCMGVVKTjumNDvKvSHl5NctSssFqWdrTgpsIr2@BFCplCtzvds11oEAEXKYW3leAgZBCflbFvKiEr0LggAz0RyC4mA2zKPrVhVBkie7Bst7g/t@/2gP6X6@dIXQUOAQaOTrQdWNNCf21lRVExQd6WV2xbKR@YpkaJQx13YZS11wokmZFjtWo6WoAQYDuf4RzG0GNA2/iBXTKG9iM5ZxNTYb31Ymsmt2zQWTq62CvLAxjSdF5KDDvepQITAkyDRqJii5WCcaUzQXFDG0UY7dnKly9RSgzs3ofTvwJu4Jae2slmmM8b2qbAaRc0LqKIbGF9DdUuaudTnqOMD4dRHpqcQXsovR0MloAdSCYl@6gc3XxWQHZwvTwvg5s0bVJ5/R2G1d49sQbC11qi/fYE20IoxtScC12XQdiBi8bRo71VDMtenlPTgywA6MEyzIkXPoqxIhmXiGzpXVnqIMMvziXRUscQOLU9UxGzq2Z4x6P18dHO5PGr1RWx56KOqPHqpECiS2vFdhYGi1wsOD2llqF7socaZag9mLOtcJ81QqJa6DR5CqNg@@C0BdCbmRy7JD0iaW5C9cNLL7IRziZsG5cOug2jkzdAXVgTJSSqKhh1xHrMKjIDNfoLRLC1c30EluHYa4iY/h2ixC5VosAR/dx7eoannoPgcbWjOLK3BiTiM46SunOOZ5r1YchmKbsurpHe7MyV@8hnARLtzTox9d2B0tDhDgEeQujnpueQS@rCXu6MqO@bq30X24C4eBffDDvNrb2TMvxyDN6vYlAAxeowK6rGTpOS1OzBTokHnffIIPCxRaLCtWsgWMVywNJg8vaWp@4fZT7wf19JVwkoRTlFgkVqj@OrQT3tXL9VHJPb6sg@v6kiwttY84buthVYiqYgVlfOjAMcPpudckeyGUaU5TYQOCahHHi5VybhfefoutYR9qw6xjPqDoN2h1GqJTB4btMxf5pUsvfnFrv/YTSNbSl2woRq9xTy4DOil6vVSlRZeULxlBk@f1FVN@aGBNjpaHxtPvKwC0BbjAy3j9TclCMzWC8HqcI8E2ZCOpNYBm@V66xn8anG4WJZpm6cbsqsyzUxqB9j9F0PgLHETquxxjYk/FSrS5ZZ/bxzSQbjsMm7fSWcochX1QOlW/RlJb0c8@g540WE7PwcKVavSDLcqDAxOZdlh5usqRyUdxXJrsuJUx9FikvYHGuzY05V6dByRJfC7lWBKnrDHsKXKlItmkb/gyv7ylNu45jfZGaAqGK7y87YK0KdM3vTTV2Td0J3mYhi6ELDwc8uv11gxastwlsS6APGs03VXp8Yui9alPAqc8RTkstP65OA4clLW3U7Wkk1T130itUz6Uk8EVbHBBiS4Ct9YpkMBSiiGWxdGOTY@qp0zUsjd2mxfxN@Cpi7kZ8yxIjmK/F@V02q7uYjU9ckUjjGVDK7IGJMjRGBn28QcXXerh9R3BbCzR18FwXPDUMXZoeGPo6gLEJQsHG69I0ckxT8h0bjCsfVxuikWLhetbAd534DScEVxL5cKQNDLbZzE1icjFagQtqmE23cK4et6iyRTQ6RFtsFLKeJaBFnRozL7yvRPh4pkO9Tka3j7Vdafk6DoC@R1Nft5D2ev9qD52hPTSGbPV69LSucQA/@mxzoJuyDrkeDHFB3Xi8tNA@Tk/Lsaz3oSfKRSYlHae/Mk8H@CIuvj/2hfCyt/6D260jd5rPZAc61raaoTGBTslzfGdsCPRpHaiFozzsuk6AhvPXP@3w0Y1GPlAkvP@0@G81LAea44/H9NYZWxOPXmhUgb4/fZvS1GerU@jSTMcdiG@cUVcMPMVg6Qqd/14tYrqmrw/xBXbG2cbA6epD87ZMB5tmSOF4D3t8L8MVKWMS4T56i5YJ5HVnIvJLPR7@DG@H6yo9GDpiPVvkuEFZWTU8R18RF8baqe6xoVB0kSqOBsdaI3uRvEpfxa@@npj@AmlsOVM0tsvmJNCxLu/Bwoq1ahV9U2MhhoMFF2u5lGroqI0LhgzajrIu2eWlbrEmlsuxy7oMxUtJcxRbsvJFyB0s/6FDg2Zs0Bb8l/hrad3Syk7OHk4G3nWBycbqe6Cf4WX9mAVdUR0br4Y@S7OD2zoyq5aEr1rCvQMK18S4cUKlcOOMCoVTLEFzTLh14AZVN1k7gGaZY49didBfOw8XLGcCQ/zqZCGjzWy1JR1UTM/os/kPdN2mhY4cFxcjgw4i6DiNjsPnKMyZ4sUEl@0MQKgLFlkAh7Dr1JaVK4hWV3/UZwqfPjEGGi63fmT6uF5zBVdQll218uhW3F@ZaJ75lQmUbB2z4e4RbA7SjW8wgE8r8D3WBqb@cKkiokwGBA4We7LbEvuj1/W6OB@aHi5nihw3jEohyzEmRq7rgNGwAvLqoH20ccaiAbGXMVdCrxpYd8YzfGdtRl03jambPh1iDe7r7MZ168NuzMT5ZDSeeMFtdR7ogqn4EPTolPp75yYgF16DaCVDzfJXD1PHxltBCws6xYVznTb@mWk5A/JZWSagtIEShsr5Csa5B93zEa7Gce0VnEjTfs85TxzlEFxWsNdQtwa@WmGb/s1DOb6PK3PCOxaG9Rz4koL0CK/i7hfFIJyspsij23X9xQvSt/TvwHnPnImrG@iMdj2JmwVBqsZ@uAAZX@pwcNeW87iVpjsWNC9wWCubjO7YE19wJ/aNvULxxl6hijtfxdiApL5y8Ph5Os4NdMH2bVpouDfawrV2tcAVJjNtUMTWy9Fl6NCWuM/2bDqmq4VvibOHG0vpVFzfd1bZO0cz6EDe22AC4T8Z3Td0nDO8Ne0nzmPHdqA3GoOgHB0bbOeBpVUeqyNitEf4bj3Qp3drMs8o2jWdENM2tLHRhfq1Fq736YsY4vuar63piujAILX/ItetvGJaXcN9RUf8Yu51Ju1yhh4aU2pbrGcY1gYFX9eZSoyDcUttZGm6xhs7js2uVNrKcFMe3yxVoCugl/efJRdxLf7SuMBK@2y5qE/P2BIRo8e2xlhXVtfoOha73rAgyTbZggDNNQ1PeoQ7LVC/Yp4IoH15N8qQ0o0yZGEagSZ7pnl0hn61qbFAqUy/wPqfoebqDk6DBY4blubEtke4RUxHy/vZqoEuEH4KEkvTJ8HGpbdlyxp1R/Sy1mCI1eax0cUXg7p0TxFfm16vTDYyFGyoEFvOFW1DEIorbNRFkjoCayR9e7e1ZEctU9Uc0wuV1GvnyulKHcE2Df2NhqNmDqXXYmB6KRzKLD2hzjUD1bFmRIeQJY2@b7@yJS2vWwOFxjIEf@iCzS/5N41th5u9rJgMmYwMnGFenoJZq7o63pAW1lk9mR4JV9cQgn0HQZZEexAy/VDYW6t5Inr4P733kQSdcKeYDzdAAdF1@/Q9ZH7i2sHtfTjwyPH8vjl9CvnGVwDWiRMsVgGiwI21DHRtrSsE1J49sdjowyC26GrUo@aYQHeIFgSLimvfEAz7TKDb0U2vl8hh731Je7iTsG/0hGA3BpxmEB6Fr4BFYMF9xexpXDbiSk9FYoSdFvPB2s9VxD0PJQPoW44vjD16l8be0eGjpyfi2FNW9k97Q3w14poet7S9g1qWY0NSrzQ3NtnJ1qL1TM@X7j1ThP1HhyICrKE3m9EQ4IbTcku3teOe4Y6ykrbWCsJQw1@tID48efwos3hLk6T2h64zMtLx4P1nz7L4mslHz1YGx2M/gNbRd6Zrox8eKEp6Bfs@t@nU4DrpuSKldZhODLBGgRkfst1hblWudGds9E5mY@Nj6DxRgnvvmXxxbSGfaGfmAFshqawlFG2opCIW8@nYsmwwtg03uq@rz1NzjNJSpzeJ3dauRUHNISe5udXaw03T/Ve1GCIHyxC@WCRFvs6t8T2NJc37u2ZMUZR1dH6m9aFeSWFtZS0DrJoctpyz95hHNgLjRYi8BB@4SjBvXUReEkYguiW84PB84AnO7to1MDchiLyLKxv8uWHPNFugc1k3qRdViI0r2m4E@cx4jwmpaHnPGW6cvnKOL1pPT1I6daZvSfjEjUXZ3793eFuE44CWN0N9@OQ5OdI83ArlZsB4jo33yPFCM3ol4LgV7sO3djq15wIq9UZ8g/Hq9lwlzzS359iz6e2TcPQ1VOza6Va1ES58okCGZU7NVX2Vzsa1jlavMbotbfYGhzNb0oPjW@QEiN59418riizTDZDwrsjs8ZaaCRs4SaFLm@GuevGgk8NINOiot4jgkV5pjT4yprgWhY0GrzLqV/ZvxRv6vlJ6fXdyU1j5hrD8DeldC0NPkhNl5QaEhRvCSEGMgh851vnQEfc11/BWrABZmaGbClK5oSCVmHQOdm6nE4uBe72Kj@8tBLeV3Hpi@G5@PHS6Zv6GVSzLr/@unfLwNZeucxk4wYsf7Hl1wucTYyXVHmtvVgdQkXO6MgikoTGc0Bcjrgcvz5R2Qfk17IHJtnsk9xz/gD7dYKFFb0WvXpRgju9PxutzDEISv5NxVa4vAX4CxrNz7pF7@ILcQl9fMQiAq@RW@69Tbkk0Qoi7nj482QvZ7OkzSY2luMjFp0dL3vgKqf/0WczPNabTddavMF1nTK4MWaT65CS/lOx248XZCmKtf@sI9A4QzNF9rULEpN5Hz67LBrTjhv7ICkM@0uzF0OlShfUcn75vuDLwaDaliylX1vSQrWVbFebqty0kg57ZNCFtT@p0cGumTmcdV54Yn9JJCNCHiM/0E4Y02ITJmOaHYQ5plLUN1TldaEFL2X02Hpr2dGXQaF0cupY09cpb3Qz2yDPLOSePoh2G1okHdTVy7cxYRdm1rywKldzN6ljuim61rl7YJ1WC27oqubdOY7siM3BlxE3SBOMf69KD8OFjNX0r/EfPQvDbYfctBwfye@ZkdDswRZvJ3A7o3iD@riI0bwfDL5CcDh3Xvh00ZKdq9Z7xnpnYeG/I0Ux33iMP3X7/dqADz7kd6PHE8k00XlaDPnEmFu4jsCrswB2s9G9sN1otsSquC8TN3b2hm14fjgsknYkHxpAZCc8oovDK9Jc8Q56J@@Fe84Yt2k76Ct6PHPJl3FV@BSnevGcdffRgHdzyzM0E5/rpe8EL57p3RMez3K2N/I05oA/v0@hsc3Qj7GL7v0PXsdlTel33uNgKcEVKDzXLvFWghSsf1FvWQGCHxsLJWe52qQUKwoP1dfbxbLqwO5dLb7GtJ1aF7atAlIGup8PPIuECdSUXG/1jC9EMb/34H@39v3Iw0nQvZDT0YusMwplkb50mEB9KWO7Qnz25t3fyydGjlaFf1kbd1ZI@/HaIen@xhd5axTYab6XfWpGe4VXwhhooVXSoVcBdMK5MzX@y9@hodZ8@BMsW6hM3R42NTy@65FTP9bRRJb@6Bh@HL5veB0GF7nVdyMOZ4QiTVWRj2z2AnhD/ZomXDbZ8Y9ujsE0pPDH8sEwqZYM4SS9/yy@@wwbu7J/axJ2tN@luGgB7eUk2gh0sIIAP98QI9uzADXBNe2LgphvsC19@fROSqdeVQoXs4MfzqkSRaZr48dAK22c0TKxJNi@C/SiqVWVONuqEr/Ik2BEk@mwA2/oeEOOm3VAoIpwqZNOHkM1wNwtCv@VELgkdhxd03BsZnkQpvq9PLdjvA/K0eXF0eHTw7GTv5PmzptyeB/uBhKWwbUgt3HXoTq7HQ@EDuoF9zz6EQfehsSA5@gEfHL/3wnIR/HbdctHqS0VbFIrfwTibF7YtSXRLFEmYQ/4EnqVGQ1E5BS@GOywxraBgN5wq252EbrICdcRQ8zRNqLQqkVclPNY8D4oVhF/91CMNxU@DVvHjoJhw8O0C4MSB4/SCFD2D3H6EKT7YO3z0/PiAhBlccM252fOH9UqBfdqCbdME9dQ36TLxOkkGUZJQV/V68kESCJMUk6RKN7Ghn5UARgewkDq4/U0Qe4ukNil@oGAyqhTpv39VmidFfN0pDbDJMFNJSBZ4njLKxsYGOQEmIfePDz8@OCaY/4P71BtJhCjICe6g8cc/7LEPM4X73IWfRXVHgT0JteU5Zq@K29roBknkFTXYG6tHcLdHtvMLMab0I0eU8@hgW@xDqWm62RgX34sn3KBmsYcO1hyVAPGY7ANKdG@a6MtN0QfoOI5@3gv4/Zzurntl29M03YmQfQQ22JU2RE1ZL/wIDE7K4w6z2MOZnok742A99HHD1@VGgut46T7LItnDL8bid2k1@o0xyOzE9tmmisHOagngUDGSVVmySTPLvkjGxwCT2xvQSLrGwLSJZ5ugJPlV8go4GCe@q2znJEFoJK9FCVFXqUtAszYGeG2HWE9qudK7X/wX0qBGwO2D@5uBeyrfg6efD5764P4F5n4hIYNe31F2kZd4hnAj6qAELCNc3/zJT/Bj0nxqU1FOO@5ZJlmQa3BRagVSIHc2W4Kw2ZTru5saENJ/PW1Bc5a28mfG/WG/dziQWjwPGlFekrYuLi6SD7aOzBcFUhR6plp8PZ3Nc8Xc6@k8p5Rfn46VYlN8PW3z5Xr2tN1qtsnR0advO2/T/PRs9hr6nRQw2P5TXsnziWqFXOwUc4nTCn6EEkp4St7Acdon@KfuN72YW0N3tw98m@RJotXCrz/zJR7EXrINfyopXsLBZEazITbEnfbbt@mmpvlTUABMc@z1enA6Q5JS1fQzAk3tLjQiFkEiLXqnRISjMJr2yXTPGAwmB9rMnDzwd8WSWBbVmGDafvzZJ8FR@@T5c0Kek@fP3xyvEWPtTCYlCE3qnoaej0AHyE5JtaMVEvgZyT/@0cY8e3HU2f7jr40kYwNvT/H2zfljdD9TCnc2Nu7cu5fPZ1VVZe6jz45@dm9vL38/WzhqFnbygryx/Ud/uLGhqtuqtNH2PKWdbJ6efsqrcp4X//gHyc7R0Vc8r5H7v776tqHgpQSXM1IiFTxyRAEnXstwKqRQIO97JN4kFDgSM/rrJEL/iw2iNHZK/@PbT18n/ERDlT5x4e4nXieK5QRzggOecuHTWaKR2Eaw4jwxk@r1OjhL/@M/QPzGR4AHQ2bbcGkUQlzFWaIh1GmUy0SjCA5FVSHd/@erX43lEOQZiJI6bZHhsQsCsdnk8yWV32nDsUWPbQ43FBNkSQrhbH/oGw5RyneVu/hgwgPcbAP3Zzb8VgI/pPt0l4gvjjPQJ2TEjxsb0v1tAQ5xLCmK2lKUuyB@hTtb9boA/Qpttrlc4S5u/pqmveHA8R1i3P1k6Uh88vdyrERT@@Tv8zgm@6ZuuE6WSxQ3dl/ebzSgvLlGbquRoUfQyGh7K5V5x9kFWXMynLimg1/krT3Cb0s1eLms8tlsdve4A1HIdIokFKZTsYMooN1iL5lgh9ghzAebc@DJeBGOBkqCNon8WazwcQFHXiab0EbaL9fDJQ7w@JP/9Cff/ZNv09936flfcDc2u2f2pS0AOoPm0oBjt1rVGw2@4fIXLXxuAI/J1XK1LHXmrdRWs9E@BrX2w8tkIZckz6xZtoPNhrTSrSaN36DJNoLk8bmRWHg3mE8j7hcEMGDqAfeAUiQRljNWrohqhFyB4xLh0jWhedZoCzgCWheaSrHQFlis5i5UDq@WKnynnRA2ZyCJ1HZDLahPyW6DHWS46REHc5NTi2FBgvw2FmVbhCyeGnGvRCOM1ljAfFG4IE8VLtFsSm2D9hWNMKO7G9WNcrVYVaVOY/1RW8TAg4IahnHkJc4S0VEjAR@G9ExEnBnzexGviahaSMjAZCnuLXBQVyA0ptPgv@ag1ZUrKnwtcKkdntSAP9ScoA46vKxAa9vtRMr7Dhwb8KN/OKJHvG5Qn8Cbglw/NkhV2VJzUuFO8UDFrvfq4QrNRoZKRqHdyIgoIQXxCgwHfQnRu93uG70LmommdTVdU3xtok21meZ3J91p19cnOn5onRyhetcJyODmnIJTdkKqiEIiV1A2E3exbDm1gt8sB9ukXM5V1FxJyZWKuZKslgu5ciVXyudKJUCYK6m5SiWvqrliKVcs54rFXLGC34UHmCLA5BBDqZCr5LjE2@YGOWbybUoy4dHK3Ho8F6lEw4M6HDwFwZkmQHHCLcm5xD/A0VBUhWxB5yjDBTRC6iQq/UEJ9zVz4mU5kgBl76L9dqv5dovEa0sI8gw3sbPbzgjzeRPctVrw325Ezho9mAuK2p5nMtsvGqADvWg0M4DyRYBSFAhFKnYapL1Ng6LUguSC8O02qFFCZru5XXf26SnSpii0AeX2UjZ3dylf7ULMxiY0@XQmsykIG03A0wx6IwBG7gvKA5jaKdBVLi5@ypMk806y6Oxub4NYmW/PG/Pm9ny@vQ3/bXqdB3fwnW9f@9Pb4lgDswhvo0hqNaVGS2oFYqkNz6LUQB9RaoGjAXeAa@bUchs7QlR0xPY/zr@YXVwjH8xyW4Rcc4ktspXATchyiS0u8fLd5/8bnq13n/8OKq0EfkaVS1wQwiWkrQqhfvRWAc3tsU0es8MGN57hI/qgR@MxetrsYqMpLEkvRVIV2NcblHIxLWJP33H6HXy1WSQvARTADgYGtJdQzBJeLRf5TkaZqSSxzRdLVLL@zLUjmUz@k5dqpZRk5ja@m/vS87zHsVwu8gnANVVWBOWywfaeZh8L@JlVxz/5mXUHl7isEKRRijC6cAlgo4QkgZnIJRrbI1y7id8uEvAjlGf1T4XnewJ@cUPzqT2Og3WgFdQPD@qVSgPtJGPziDadrftbcFXgf7ABhSCtPoC2@nV9BDp4q58rqC00Sz/UwDwHmSZ0X@Pv0Rv8kRMdf8ev8UdO3uDv2McfedzF38lr/O118Xcywt@91/h7/AZ/zwf4a30pl1Nq/OYFJU9GqSjzzSlPyVSD7qzR@pLvzqr0Axy8uqOCzhl8ASWVy1fSidaX2MBJNfheCK6nNXS/ptUrtW5dDUCDxUAYIppe@IXTFHt9u6qSNA5Y5CoFxxVwwhou4JHJVRTHTf74W1/7WrJeTwpJ@u2EPPgJXQTqUiB4hJh5lhP8Jh3kDyrd85K13eSXmnRwqlBpNzGwDQFcok42lU1FtmRdVrpKFxwmkV0iD@Wh0lOo3SYbRJ7JMyKPHKUHLgN@MrhMuU/kAZFt2QYwCAWX35F9dPXhNoBfHxC58DNxUVRXkXUCCVmopNLPxCkdjClfdsiHQ8fzs@MW1yRJwr80wAAXFVEWi2Ybv3DR5F@@bElbbbVSJiIyudhpvmwl23yLx/2O1UqedGfGRuslD1qJzLPGgD4k4Xlg1dcSUqslsQoAstEanc87nYMn9zsdCbvHFjEamd0MiPvd3TqI/@C2k2jUdlpV2nuEPUhC2t5pNXICuosZ6BtU8CMPDcuws1LmCx4LxHBvbFACtF@evwQjKHWOptD5GdzOQ8cnLbh0mJFEg6XzT1qxR@qAA2El6ZMVGJYckGvbBbOBLHQ/@IM1@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@L4pJ1V4VCupaX5cTFnGfASqXCoNMkX0yVM5XgV99IkwaoTOyHel8uk98qbe2CBo0/b7rqQIlauzDqyrx@YVTx00fzmh58VRVf9zbu3s1VgDRlOUHuT3DTiWyLC8RxHTom1L7g0uKSyQy5c5fDd@HdZLW2S2tWKRdIIlljnkISxDopA40ldauglJEmnNnHTRxAheAUaotukA1OpXe8cBVmoW6gJ9i@cdlH/1wPDtIjXTLAgwzQ9iQmsehBLMLC6VXXIyCHHUFo9Ejj4hH5GNHBhtxzhRzj0iR5NNFNHPY6erS3f3CSVbcFklAf7O1n1WfP7yUUfCwsnmlwDp@PD/buP30OEY4eHew9O/jw8OOD50fg75HzxRH1EmFfEfUZMdeK53PyCffKfaMZhmZMDKNzPpmcvyavTLNjQtVaEyibM3CJZ3SgSGNtUbwanLrpaa9eae6YHuTd97/x7vv/7N1vfOvdb3zj3W9898eff/cbcP4Qzm@x@7f@faWA1x9//q9/692v/wZ4/hc4fx/OH/3481/@Kjvp8x/A@d9ifn8QnDE4dnKA6@d//Pm3f/Djz3/he3D@WnB@7/r5iz9afX736@tPjPft37oZ5lv/Ac7fZrhC2G/9OvPD@zX4X2dwv/C9d7/0H9n/j4IfOn/j3S/9AV6Ch3/5vT/6b@@@9p9VtfxH/@7d17/97utfe/f1b777@j9V3/3yv1Pk@OW33n33d//89377z3/vX9H/D@n1t9/n/@57//JP//c//T/@9PeC80dw/kdw/ehP/zM017/63e/j/9u/@1e//338/6@/@Ve/@52/@vn/hTp@hTn@5tf@Pbv@xS/@17/81W/@@Y@@@pff@dFf/srv/vn/@Qv/9y//17/4n37nL/7F19DzV37057//83/2tW/82df/zZ997fM112/ceP38Pfw//wfwef98vg@e9ynXF/X5/KfKz9@FGotUgE@Au//5u1/@OWDwXyLk3Td@iK9NwLnm/0NVoTA/ZE//P3Co18uMITK44PzOu298C0n0PwOJ4B/R65vRw1IIe/jm4gHI@qsrIv3zH3/@b35AnxJGtUGnpbAnL6vlzBYYPVuVStCbBzNWEOXnlrFFCIKUvokSainsmyjb3n3/q@9@8E/fff9X3n3/57EPF/KV7F5WUG6Z7gPAwnvAIWDxfeAQ8FNIv5Oho3hC5lN42vi0UM7Ztl379NNPuc6lhO/n7F6ST@FHPg0PwoLw/Z0gKAxDf3yhh4B/8@XLNs4Rx/wkhSGXVHYPgnD1D6QkqHcyO5KisiDjUtpksUgNPHLlXCuWdanf36rCj8ClWt26yAo7LVAEadQ5Z4RFUgKsGxJRtGxuK6cBoJRncKRq78r5TGlL08C6zSDeDFWFtkIFrZAj00yQ5DSYR0Z/AJpuUeeUsKmAKQ2eclM63Qz/EiFlkiPEZv8aRzJUa6IHfsQsdFJHEC@cqqZOrgDJZBYTDVRjJExZ22I@dAKeppsHC4XO3mWmYJGDA0fHIegeGAT1egYj1lkW4ZEVplEmNCuZTB3KjbFZnGynjCim9ygWiFnPHJPOVn3KImYQXyMkR4ZDr2NeUflMuX4fEqxP7xPEhcgp2pcv641yfdpAdG8ZdTLTzD2aJ0RWz0wbb@G5TnFCPC5x/y1kpVzPZBplTBALyaoHjXCspAItHC07zv6yOoA7LsHa2SXkDq@UeTbHsoEEY9B4zSygERDAIbyV2QqKQ/@hk55blOAbNKkgFcLCd6iqvMO0ZwQAvIIgiiKBExc27JBdCJ4yVBmaLNwyDEOGcgTlgMiDUJpwGVq/jECQPnjTL70SVc3XwPqoEfRydQ4//0ZXy8jc5hRXQl2QQFOWg2@czjkNYPJyjru41IKVUpsamYNXkUMImmZ96wsfmFkk1ubmJpdo8Dn@KZ0bzkgScU@rdL0btFxqR1UJX6zw6G3QxX@MeI9xwXeWo@4aFpO8@@oPEnm5lOA2k/QT3YQlRO5k2Lm7u0XuAFnpPeY3pcvKhEzOyTsJRsbtTIZXIdGGA09blIQZio17QRJ1/IN/gjIWSZAjzTW9LJelIjELN7GewGDy9OnTIL/U40Wdy0CLU3MKPuO84GQygehGD@fgs1lRzIrZbHAX6Z16iIFDpKHBXdxE0pO4vaeUyvghWVsfIl24t2/fAm9wSIvqIRjgzEnqar5MAwllgyku@NJGWY5t2GBZs3BdqZqvcGy0gijFPCEpyhFwpAkuoEwBa6c5tgqLsVd4pJJqGUxqhIQaE1MAxtAUFZRJbKUqfW2HFEpLj5Cz@COOQbJxb1wcEC0RZflLlQvpMHD/Kdl/@vjxwZOTcbtNOIN@wtjojF1HNzwvhWF7T@4z9lUrxXSi2cSyn1RVlJHcQVVGNs4c3j8@fFYljGJB1aVoOWp0Xj2gS0XhEuPxJ9sJF8feXYPH7285/DO8VhekSKkVkN/pRINL6AYaZcCn@IezRo6NAbLvY29wz5mSlJzl@axSRJM5jdPEkJ2fdSYE94lkm0qAdMDVfCKUF3PeuBBis0/o0SDHKsccgkIdJFcph44ScyilIgI8ZR@wy3GNZwcngPnkKVFUWSTHTteETDU@JVOR5vPYGRlOVpjT2CiRTsyRgxBW3TLsgT/cxI8E8y2ZjxFosyln8afmcnBV8sWsUii1NzasCwHxtCjLXOBaxTk8XghIkw/gINwHHPkAvOAQ5oTDD4CTYJD/8GmNMS@@jktSkPtnvssrBZALaQ7nKwJ83Dh@1IDo0M6WJ/64xMZnn/mk0Th4cl84fIADE9MhCRc6CmZPHIqUcXoT16ChA0J65scmfqpN7Jne2NJm0IiBXlsNIIiPE7CJ@XzeB5yHD4jaUOkji9vD61ynPl1wz6caR0BA97nE3XAshivdrVbrb5V8CfJWrb7NqSoHHtwWaBVmfwO4jS5a2ZLYj7freUXOKOFMB0nzPF/zIFO5XFna4hIKz8Mtl8txtAERrmpwhC5leivX60Ig4/MKXcnE4ecCtGldjY4AdnpnAZuTGSyGQAAZ@C6Rw7ASCwuewm4BioJre@nXaWuBRJHv3s3hiFQuL0dlJ5Q0ZA5VupnL57CSwA9824l8KZhCg/K1E5xl@KRXB3eihQVmjVlJ8ASfUP7lyjKXaCagaXPNdrP@//2v3eTa03@8fyBLs1nnpiAh42fgjTD0TpZ@HPfYebr4P306ij/e@B89dR4/dUYO/KEnfIwCvLb412pLjzf/A8mJQqkGqjDnG1NgJ/jl5QI8/s13v/rXv/Sf/vrfflPEI3iKPP7mu99h/r/2r/H6ne/@9Xf@2V9/599Sn1/861/7V0HQ3/zab5L70MZnb7Qs94/uAJFBmwWbAd4ONrhs0NXaTaWSbx9As2uS9na492UDoLfZ2zoENx2p80g0yTeDN3ganmH1RVwDXee3x42crPLbwS7bDfKxYaNYC@I3evWeo9OPjdd6ookffcdXhFi8fJ6vOTZuW1cPp1mh70tfDOrn9C3mmlEfiLgRimtrFkTvOr2Z6PkzUFp0x3LcehIMuGQYsEBugGaPY9o7uVy@CgUTx854B9TDj03HggoiHLj3eo6NqpdaKGWaigxqEZ5KOatmN4ydUqnaE3XL0NydQrVQzsJDNEG@U5CrA/HTx48e@v74GPpxw/N38hWIgBuK4dY/O@VqoQAtguczTZp4G7@czLo9YWMDuglD6wlwx/lzT1DLbYjcM916PZncySmqoFRzcnnORUTF@hgqjbyc35bgDjaohPPy0F83yJ4xMLBjpRWhbEtjrGJwAqgGzi44C9tSF5wmOCvbkgnOSSOnyNvShNU0UrTBYaYySMks1nZ2qFwEPVbVdmxjzlWzWta8oISv9vv9@dZFZvHAaRcCe4IqmQtatnsRPdaEGFyVTLKCuQgEH60PNXwRLDuo8mqhzNeatcVzqcjX2nNud2T0TA2/q92SL67HKoImwbAmIKEW4eZV13H8atfoO66xAMwpxRCQZeg6QJ6fR8m1ZEzx4npyxRjQ9OI6lnyBn0exwmxx8zlUKqM3tMgXL7jE1vHHuUYDGOQiX1LzhXxBzRWLhZIK2k8lXyyUoVLlolxQVWip@Uq5UppDE5Gktwn67TiyfxE2nSrdQD@lVdkOkM02Sb99YloX5ZzA2noqXYPuMvGWS9w5/lhtNNYPz6RAk/xYFRr1XKECrhy61BztXFVVUHNCThGUHP5vcaj4f394Ff4qXiFWTuVOcF@YJ6DEgf5qk0e4rYTvkBPHoS@93DP0NRD7Q43uQbPvOp73d4C5p9mnLOi@yTZjjYIeaviNNW9k@sM1EM/HI9xSxnD/wTAcjLqQQRStDOAeXFzLcVYBlMjzozWlfBxtfw7EYPufA/jx4YcPT2L3k4O9/Ydckdx7@uT@lVshACqQRwcPTqLHEgsNoxYiFD978OjR1cfgln/6/Lg/cVw8uQdPn@cXl8gL3xXi8nAsA0XeFElwwUfUAVBVJRtgM4YOhcPXlO7mK@Ru4CwUF04ZnZ@wF6FML3qTib1LV@VOwrejNPpOa9cgOts5CAfT6K5@gVmrlCocNya2c05KMuk5lqXhB@P7G@A51DzSNQy00iwLORGTPndcq3du9owN0J0gjYqCH@fGTHAPAclootN30UFLxj1ie/gpd5yy7loTg0zGZK0n3NALna45GEK3fu6EAFxX0wicX/SA@Eb88G/28Fka1O9aiHUdnEtwe0/R/K4keH6f5x9qvlZzjdIL0jiYAqdCu9HcWbaczfF@ga/aA5zitMZoUHvj5tYEFP@NjXyZ/MWv/vBv//A7O2pL3pdxbPbxo7w6A41DkWrdOlGKl42dvLOLFoKLNudWx0iUB/WqVygqOxJ2qm5dzuwmxo730CjXeB5sb5CmVQ8N7geO26uSA9sEWfIADp7H/lM/3ddegB3cwQly5L4qVcHuO66u4YpbtM4ItbUCI02kYwNqpVwoV3JqOVuulPMFpVgoZBU1q5TKpQpkTFbKSrFcqCjZcr4CqlO@AqEFMM@ZiSdJW2TPwiGdLDPjpK0qoLd1/Dr1Nh1mEIcNLsEWRZA3KS1NElr0PCG8AXF4smcPDAtw4OiQT1/X2zLr0CcTRSa5EgHMGtFJ4sGDfRnLew8fcKnYvszzPXwolGW5dI/nDRqyX0btkHdYnDJu@cf77EGW70G1ThgC3C2f54f4cFDE4X2eN/Fhf4/RtY8PKsYHsFMWwh6s8KEEYDY@gM1JEbyOsAHYHksnTzN6gA@YJIY8YCH7EMbzH4bZwZBjBsYQPAxLurfH84fsYW8PQ/ZpsQsso1/Ghz168LwLD9DmeH4AjoELrR04BJzY8nheB5c@08APvwiOG6rbvsbzM0YeJBDPTym0pp/yfCf0x2Q@DnJTQOpW6YPCSr1LHyr443k1zDSC5aKHHM/no4c8lO3hw4@1od8zBuyYueyuQ0kfPsxp5nRy8KD74YfdwaDrzvYOPjzGoP39h6DgzCZud9ANInY7cDgQa/@hqp2OZlcPKPVhp1PVrJVBX@508pp9Jagz6xiYQ4j1GnIWHANMaNTZh6D9h51dbdUiF4qwg0JnBPcuHvdGcL@ndVlQeNAgep92u3wNmgFYCK0Uh7YPrlPB5nkKQtzOjjTddWr4PK0Tma4GnjWLcrtGA8gIjBe5NsfwfgqvGo7Api9mzWldbten9VKwyLSf4ltTtWDy2Y3RjlIpVDe0HUXNZ6ZVfNPY6SdJUlB2SEq5u/WGpJ6kd1SwZDb41s6OwDeV9k6x9AIlXBUvO6pSruZllaTZY65UhThyUiYEL@lmqb1TKlQXkUuljCap1VIJ9EGgjw9aRRfHPDsklTo3tNN0GrNOB82gPLTgZEYLbdb6qWl2WmeZJLN0bVpXamxXYSJfwZZK9XAL@4mOO5cShnQACKc7chUXSKV4pVLmIQ@SlEqDMJrP54w4F3kwfi4uvIuL1jwSlRK4FsOWn3zl5PTk5FOQVqC2zLJUM20EA35HroEyrxY8fvhwXzx8Gj7h7vTiA9SYHVfcRxm3FMJU59DrBOwg8SH09WDChn4Qx3cdSzygK4lB7Q4Dwj0dxGCnWPHk4RKeZ0PnnKUMkbwa3W4Q3/HGzfvNHtHqDXBpPZKiuSJa@pxqGZ1Go96pj4zR2J9BEcNYXyZ0Z/sFmkOP5Z1@fAR3bqPRL/quMwoCOnV5Dl3eNDEVBLIHSuDEzQLGTp0IysuR03upZvRaD3fvv1e/h2hqHbh3wQg3XNdxeTA6@Vp/x65PbE/rG0eGiy@uHz7dBO0H931I9YmR3iStA4TeR6NpLjRcYi/y@GQySmlCo5te9sJB8sgDyZT6Slj8Cxwkhpzz/LzWr5PUCwB9Dc/uJkn1xHvpnXwNKHaPdNLgJb/sv@wTlRTzNWobpRAXNEFKKaSAlq43vgxKG0N9SqpVyE1Q5aeAFRMDxFAbNERLj815Ta9bJCWQaZrSKF8b1JsY/RIv2wJoGYLQvGzjGPcnaDC8nkDn2YDmXpsltLo36dLvvxC5q6hysTYFP6WUrw2hvrUX05pbH09co2bBYzAqTmiJtRrQFkgIaN5cpt793FfT20KhzvxqFNUlaiwdsVOf1mzcURI4pZ6rQ0CmmZezhTLoMoVSFlQItZhVitlcNp8VSugL@kO2kAVPsM1AQ0pZKZ4QPitPZVHJKoaSTckvzd7LdPY0JQMdKPHSWd85sCcjgj5QZcit9BnuWjqjbgGJeg7RtgXKvCBkalguoP2QjM3skGI6NjSLRUgLJLeVsjZTCLR5MhkfNNvV6sF0/BUISgmvd4qZkpx5k07XUhvpume8pjMI90xgEA2Ii5KJFn@8ATwdzBwQbzJqQq2DSymp1Wazi2UtydmcnINimp3LwTbf4NtZeaOoQJ3N6ZCYQphkiQ@Wg@bELfzGHTQeLAPqUKmoNU7EMeoEuedO6Oh9rqwKFamwVZDZiDlDwY0DEYm0JakWH7yGkEwlkyU1mVxY2ulkDacmN/jFXBG1v@kS0lQSRDZJ3lULxR0eFEC@yldUHsAWEhdzSeQw51tkXzM8zcVZBQ71YJIH@/2Cm1/MtxvcVOQORqZlallimzp@bc3UT0UOldgs6ZoD0td8bMsitwelPayK3DMwBg3qah7gJviExadbNmC0doCwSmdc/OFsaICFJHIzOgHli9d9oZYI3sOkliHIl7hn@Mb/tvoCf6UXj/ee4u/BbgLX/ZPdL0FYBfzLLx4/f/r86QP6VvfitcsvcuxyRKKL@0FRryVqdKQYZ@UhGabWv/@xizOyRNrAF5dJRhTEBn0lfpel0go2Z5E2CPmibx9kthsv2L2F77IBao7uwN0kbboq2DDRlicfa6BQ7pAkVLnmjpqqmms31RKoJdB1NWUGqqpKDXLRSdC3MBvA39MLyPR2poEvvn@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@sNXPum4GYT4TTyFr6yjos6ko2MtJUkYGuTRnNem7czdCqaDoe82LJbV4jR2sAXH5e9tmz4GVse/RkGfaQeHjyGT8bWK49PbaUlqdej/Q4uAxCERoK1uo5BCg3gly0JcrkVTh2znyC00u9@7pdVtfi3f/iLl53LzqeqqlYqlaKiJn7yk@2JPfGMXuMnEPEo3GAMmEg3e8isJ86pYXtiNOZAOzvTxo9jmXY0VkHYNnNmECtyiDrPJSY22mMMPhy5wDEKAjqpObCNHh2x4M5Qo6bV2mFbevVSFGyLgEGSpfYc3UMoXeO40NZh9po70LMUB9nCXXGb7TR3wX2AQaCfEbD5atwHC1TgMQKNzNE7njVxx/SF0RSNp7Sz5C5EgRQ@wO3SNgA6TYJ@WwBJDH31tagsyx6lGtW5CW4RjZuvgTrCfQBRgj3ErRkZa65nUEjTBl1BRBCaTxrQa0LabUjbYhE61DdFS88AsoTljkWywYzjPgD9klLBBLWTmNsAUAOZ8gEQAMqQChCbbbJNcmlyYWYytcXObnPc0QNfndTCrcc4jIbYekCmKHIN4cALzEf8ai3yRVDDIPdiniEShoOt6qqDAYrR6RMq9Caww/S9UQGu8yHWEC0auXt3kat63eylCS0R4j81xziIS@vBXp1XQBZa8ndApIJKlclgZX@wzHZA8QzNLnCdwDbLq8WiEh4f5xwH//dmWuTIK1VFA2pYgKC@WKvQgWQQGcnO6lAn23WiqKU0iTKvQ951mim6MU00PNGa3hHVT8PAOeTwJ4nwm1AgrE7iA@MB3943rMvRZURwj4ARNqEbHvpDjQmDnmGZIzP4@DoKvUM/jB3FgqKYFoXumy6YwnTxWLhjWyqnpDHaYoc7mg/6mpiaJ/iyViGNNxoLoQncNdxBLEhng6qvugMV6o0dm2455qNowtflgCNARkECTxzfYNme2Of4AbegbmjkeI6glGDpIOdjjukWag5@@Z7GxVVYXdfQTkPaZIkxEIk@6hG1QlKU0WxckGBH6NI0Es1wFywopHHXMkaQpWeGQd/b9qqSNADFb9LFWWnpsQl8NXxgQvdje9J9RmDp3Dw1pRPcQFlw@vh6N0UOWEBXxObH1nGBsTmxesRynFNimacGm@9Ixbdvw29HFLNg/GSBsosTCFtFtVfNZXEgTMkyKDhLcCsxZzkbi7uRmqWv33PKRqqDNXpJezATasUyzjQ7Rl96XHLBYIo38zi6W12doPGQgmcxErnQMtnGT0nc@SmZFoH2vVSao/XrQRSMKeI82jjFJ/i06I0t06dObuwaZwQHQzjsY0Bo6p0gC9iKobQf0A6Atj1oWbiDnO9WoeYykBO3l9Kh6QUC3iZ3SE7lEBBSRlCWAcCBVV9fxg5hEBXL4fk9qBiRTh6hXIHWOepBGO5QFbAfxg@5G910P78Fe5ONAB12OjStOmHNInwoxB6wdSA/06JvQGARcrgiJxspPgNoM3yaZ6ij@FejM27nqCypkuuYsgQxBKQGLFRV0FDk0E1ZF19awzUa9zSPfY4DuR6Y/vz8XKSbJU5cUzQ8/PqY59iaJY0HJqjDjuQbo3HwnWdTl8Yh3oVLYB8dFMfD8c4Uldp65e6M3Tmu79WDZZmpZN9LYud4hh/XGozO0L6CDPc9ylAPTPphPj0VrBJl/Ke2sxch/1WR/4Ryco5ICEE00@wsq2cBWbarn2b7571aEHBGGyQgh1o0Qk/cwtQNH0Ze6DLH/QjC8VGORkFd65SuMwBMPJsxWCTNShhCzsLH4Hls4mpu2zgne66rzVI0PI3QyMCpGVV7yAy6fRoCTtyh/ILtp2lOm7P2UvRpFB06tWhdDwjyFPZcNyJlm6ti@JSFTyF8ysKni0TDZJvTNlPJ0GuOxUGux2XpISSimYUwc7YR6SKEYgY9nCgMBULOlvxw@apep7FDerMnqMd6yBjAE2MguJGSmi9azVbb9ozzrXZGGgCz85QQUOOAutmmND3vRW6kvnVmjR1vyQu6D6reBPlGL30YcAPjFSxjVEGUMRi9TNw8cjAK1hoxhSAoMGBAPQwCUTXY81Nmuhbt5ksDgXGa/ILGLGPNIDNtqn0FQYEfqEuM9IywcUTtGCL0j4oE2YQQErYc9q3JUDp84joAE8IK9PN4ICJnJNlOAiWvNBUma2q0kmK5EoQwm0B2VFfrV4sShkNVNK8ExYo5D@o/nv2NL5z9PrSL1bmnDMs6jBoXbyq4Bh1UiKC5UKqSRj1Wr5ADaUuzDBd6rgOmnwa9NSSzJYVmBksHi@Cdm74@TMUqX0@z@qHbBfA2X41YYVavQxFnddYsWbsIScoIHkXzgmizkBGC@EyAAA55ZTQjiDaNR5vW60xwkOmaaOexTE5pJqcsCoOerslkO4gG1tNh2L1g9bRBO8XV8TzgU1g3CmrQmCeedmbg0o5Xk9EYraowzYXMoVwQ8BCq2Mhnentl6s1YpmNC6woCZMRrCHr/b3dfu9ZGsqT5m7qKtIQblSl9YYNpgWgLELbOweDhw26voNWFVILqFpJaJQzyx3lm5sfewO7/vYS9lbmH@bVXMRtvRGZVliSwu/vMnH3W/TSSqjIjIyMjIyMjIyLl2uqKMy3wyvn4VyyjhJRGRskvzQYiK4jBWARvOLIHipmM98Ck8GeWeR2guZtZbjqZMh8V4L@S/J/xzEPzf3n2YSldspx@WPKm/vtPeXgOyloT1NI@yqVnEMhOYqnIPireRCPOaC9JfG8dhwNs1O6heveqdqJOXtXV3unOX9X7w1P1rnZwgpiHN6fb@40dRf/XD47rHDuV/HtLI4B5vOKR1t8OONX@Sqn0TDHkncFwIj44uR1Xnh@Tmv2K8IUg34z86xdX8qPQD8ZbUquO5M9w4Qk5MTJp@NiR0B61TeBYCeuwexiOXhWVvfBJg4Cmd036SDeksgSEyobE2tqjiBT@NumktCfTDrqebIyufNzgdIltE1ycer3BLVWnydKDdCMwvlgo@GZWKsEVgk5BacLF/343BU/qR6@PFcJtdg4PdhsnjcODY7V3eEQ/37xvHLwkejaOT44a26d4xQVfH@429ho7NX4gCJQKCgEwv9zQ1vEhFAoozlRp/wrdkC/gjX@ldNGs4/QH6tZnR7lILd3QZzgOSZ5/DDpLGw7xkhLnPJ5MKrdYO3r5tlk6V8Fv0AGMssQaeuY04kTSiyW1ya3RdNw662dk@nNeqHzZ5Rl7PVFI3k3Tl7c6/N1TBjhvczshSZkd7OL6S2MlgS8wCCkDmhp6RLABymzpquqXQdjPLS15mwxyi1pr9wZIHCOtiZlN/0DVF2YztuEwxfRuEkBxYtzoQ4qVN@IHxPf0YEU3Ox5JAfU0fiAF1DN5MPZ/DRrYXalVXeJmfHgDg49akwe/XA/3WHFSz@MH2z6rVesaJxk3HlJfXSQXPVwPafsM1xpeXDkbucSIoUrE5UNsoXoyMQLadhPLk@4miy1bf6hkhuRpF3nLtWFI7kPAW@IG7KT97pi2zlW3oE6wfQ76mD00oS57fl@MBMnmlnlPrSMEtar9cMN@e8R4Kj6DHw6YAdXFRKXxiOvtSr1O8K31qOb2TIu@tiJyYnVjpPkaAtszCPwRMAQob8sLv81Z7dl3EWAGXc3KuWhAHAkjwd/s8sTOnRuY@qwK2q6R@yX8@NHVRPaSKmFiyWPsaIg@Io2xLPakTdMcZ7HKV1lACravBsNxKGOYS/eABGcg921QaeojEPy5upVqDXSYbrE/6FuNXhAX39PqBTHlt7TKHC/aZSy@ksT@xPlhPxLLFNDxL3ABbZKI31MRybZAXcIFUiyz9lUD2Mg7TiI7/qYi2uesV7d2t8/yf/vZOy8WL0UsSIZ@Y5bD/3J1AVYS@KGISY905LGZaRqoE91coLa2UmlpiVlugFVpfoXdsXrR2ojfiUF@9jn8Eqaf88PPn6tSKw/JpK@DiK5yiXTzVNM06XGdc6U3SZbsJGRJ1ufME49hxvL6BXwQMAobRJE@5AgsBqkLEWhCiAgxvbu46ZJkEcXMDHcM31VbvOdILg2Bg4A9HsWfctvV5S23mGy5lEXOnBHRnoFcdl1r48br1Qy43YfBkfz@dnDrD2Iny8Pvgrb7ILTfhVt@@X5YsixZsL4d7N8eACuL2x8CS3337gcsi@QstJjTY@b0FrOxvfnhFn@eGTueewQGa@9wMEyAWq3d9HukfSuTgi0nFVwbTKIQHZ/s1o@OVIYdxypUl@QefME6WgwC9iNzfxK7v/dZ2BVipcn8S5Qn8yRl8zH/HprMc4l3j6jQOoin6RELi@R6nC5tqVjq6ZWFVQg@n2KBaCiXxu6TkUFRUwP@0ixj45cMmtVBZ243s7L4hJF9TKLp5olubJ9y8RmErN1UdDya2IDsXbN/ibPX@eP3TvTjimlHFCwEyKHDHdKkab2hfcIxLpyngoVCegQfGBYzpDiGEgU7a2gH00gprWH/eYZiRhIlXHRhS6xr5VijJvrxolFz2GSHZcCHLVS/FJs/vTAinp9s2gPqJoteLr0EkZLpUu0XNldQ9fMvG/H9WLlknazGCrk91xYZm6bB8hxHFhr2xv2FHuO0YG1aPEw3RdL2wabyf5@mZJVItWRoPrcz5iVBXltdffo12NO9MNXzfxa2rCHT8nN8PaT9fQIymkR8UkWc2zjwzPuEAR4gnRw@mQkzVZFUnTlrSqrvvBjZ@BEuYi4hZJCxsH1FcKdaddXdFG7zocuKZEPnIjN9sKZw3FGZNTPU//JwcxDIX23v0e9vTyYbCsG49gXnVq8HoyhI/FasIBvrEZyL08@C0ajPxeTE/xpQcnzQ/6A7CvujiElYeoWXfOpm96Srz@/FMO0ZWwM3ojif@e2VPyY5Z7FU4pVid3WvsV9XTzhxRpetD@aQNTPKuJbseRT2H0KAZTDbJbB8sJfL46hC/xMOngFJZGJ/lxzTxv0qbkwR0pqbnKZaG061bC1Pj343avt9hGN4mceRynjfUUUX7FI/3HOd9AV02q02VZ@Qi4b9HNXyMvlChqvSM1IU8MxNg5DRxHNrwcJZpjm4xwE07pgv8H2owZ1Yz/gg3y@W10tr3zvcu7439q6b3597T9rVjKLF1@9fRzej286vl4OrD13VU8NfLu7ak4@/KbX6DOm@1Mp3ks6pvFYtcvqZ5wqZwL4vMedqBH/g1FS4@qtgXCCXVLIP33ik@AJDxZvmCs4Qp7hUPbk2XAgnlHH1url2Xu1XSxvXzf75BtxgxsvV8XJ5OYcH39EqSjIGNXPt5vgca6ptdQ36H/gmP75fRx@eKj48pSev/VE42K8dvExZ46AAwASmT0MwHmLAdxZwjobT2UI/uM1pM5mnwLEOFCRngc/Ny3Ay5VN@mGM6IWFGo@KRNhvd8d@J6yyUCjfD8YDfmNB9sJb6HH52FsxBf0muWuwEzdAE@PP1bdFdUiZHRUJ5OpFzhnxZ1LUyvItcC0QTNVkcZs4yGXjdAFHt7dA8d6JC4LevgAQuxvsst/ZtbvI1ecRqUYGteDkX59Z8pFg6x9cefaWPIbsvoAnW3CM@GHWo@/hdxhd5wjaqMZ8k8xGSw5oi3uCARH1iDwCuv0kEEMIviM5V0CZOrXmRIineNWxcQIBreuP/iIQAHI9kUBbQWcCW9qoJcD5LYRqhWU0mer7AlxUKreif7kG@zL9muhGXd6U4k2QZXde/ItCSh5RfbeGjl1TLWdXyppopbJFi4avUgKWLtkevA5pWE7UT9HqEtNBiISEHvrIHnG5/OW4/aqLN8xh5eZ@feZ9PvS/Ie0EqKVWgBT4pVLELZbKfknJfVCYp5s20VVWsvBRopNsFUkmSshsPlY0K40ErTApvxUMpXBm/2Ey9yFtvfpoz@vLmUapOzODx@6a81/y9okc@xjJV9kW6fXw6eoDwx6w/01xa6Ie9Hxx9JZ1@AzbLEDWVkup8y4cyk6qqvZS0OCENDnZ@nrZb1QTKctlIHJ4zma3NF5mCVjJ@yE2jIX4@MxNrzhyxqMRtLjPh7tilh9rh148sEAwTjKbMzN0ylSe68sQCi1KPTLPiJzQzwalr01O8Cs@hz/hjJnsaOVMuO//lgmB@J50X/780gVjoPsrMJ1NamuBAVR7qTj2wiiRtT6YhzhcSB5YVOG4zEC/FLszgj2I5YQsKIylm6B6/0ZROCpQN@943hHj5xfmP4hPnpU869rAX3Kkathk@@yk4KRfQcRDhmuGrgANScP98D6eOrPDdspOhzge4sorjlgSitbIXnEYXxmIu7@GbdtmkSgV1CMi3YRRYL6Kby0u4W8BHbHAL0QqLS4gQpv5EDBo0Z56uiCNmoHDoywK4F17aSMjIyeyJr6AtOPo6Xke62g317ThsT4czIiI5aUmrOM4/3YTtX3de4jz3ebn0tGyR7IM@Di4Vnj5LXBCISObFCkK3V8vPHMc6G27L2XAeAD21j4X@LfFm8CHo9wOnRisGF4xwa3Iw@hB0Co5zFMSHwIALVsbJJDwVBzejthh3SOnyiRnhRxd5chxGHIZPrM9yXNzmszLPwaFVctpMQ/0hxJXWsTdvd4DTYT6wgCOt0AOVroMxEeWJq9Io8dmzxoV1l2sYoogaiASwziZiMvQH47BNI8OWLKdHoOQYJGms35nChNpr93y4zxXmIUANWRQwCJijpIdwcPSh@e/CQemOmTN234xMkaTfgOcKTfdgFJL0TQjMo8LVLNxpgE9eNY7V8eHeybvaUV3R9zdHh28bu/Vdtf2ez7hxUM7ZV9Srw32SLvFpupyaH9KDTO2Yamb4hVM7eK/qP745qh8fq8Mj1Xj9Zr9B0Aj8Ue3gpFE/9lTjYGf/dJdP3wmCOjg8UfuN140TKnZy6HGrppqT1FOHe@p1/WjnFf2sbTf2GyfvucW9xskBGsOpfk29qR2dNHZO92tH6s3p0ZvD47pCx5zdxvHOfq3xur5boPapTVV/Wz84Ucevavv7Ux09fHdQP1LsJGD1crtOWNa2aQuLlrifu42j@s4JOpR82yHiEYL7njp@U99p4Ev9xzp1p3b03tNAj@v/dEqF6KXarb2uvaTOObmvUIXGZef0qI7oIlDi@HT7@KRxcnpSVy8PD3eZ1sf1o7eNnfrxhnL2D4@ZYKfHdY/aOKlx0wSDqEXv6fv26XGD6dY4OKE14/QN/B1cGuR3ddw4vlOjqrtMYLhBoLdEpMOj94AKOvAAeOrdqzo9PwJNmVo1UAEeFTsndjFqkIh4YndTHdRf7jde1g926nh9CDDvGsd1lwascYwCDThkvCfWoUZPudcYJ8JLvhKzOoZzPR5O1dhTtd23DWCuSxMHHDc0tzDZdl5pmheQNMUyooQD2Az8a9uw0p199CFAoP@sRWa@jSaOKdo53K3TiqxjwTLJi1Naddango3sd7TSxC/pZyqooxNc3Fy2cN07vLDiamL4uI4uPeRudpE19sx5IP5Q21e4Qjbbar2ttWije9xqud631Eyh8bUa2gz@UClX9xFZ/LDzhuGnUhG6b6YItfWdPuj0lCSX4ZJC/e94cYVHkauKxU6gq8G9FYCN6SiSY5MrHKWQaGTPeuS5TZpkywT/DjU7cMWcAV9ot2AnpZ5LoUFEf/qfkx@yOFgPSDqLuatYxCaW0Qg/BqYZaYSdhvmP9tkNu9xkIQqCXy9zJbs57PkLl4NBB1kvdB0uO6Z94GXO/Ur1i@Byqnp@uj4jy8fOOh1dZPbdrMLE58@aZEqPS2HEPcvhT2vMH67BRryiYTXlpthYrY2Wue@kOjySPKWdv784OoMQdL7XtR8b77CbK60825h6/ip@LnMLiSCQM4QWvCbXO@ePV@dSgCYYe6sTSULtQ14sWnWMv0lc@JYKXqHQbdiB5w@t1VcBr@tEElJkb/ye3SZW41F4Z2NPcvjlUe319uneHolOYPtsffX52oYTB6b96Mnne7TDWTs4Lm9I6zjpafzKmiU7pPjwTLFSLCXszwxcLKIgsnaZQeOH8ISO/TbSnkwQZOhuhKTPfbjoZQLQIaPYRf2RY/h17szUDJBLddVFb679O1bxfdKVmAe0M0tvwqN2hz@AHU9/M8XjDmkG0izGeUyIc2l3wXIvg0rszcKbGw5tQZFCxvCxBDrGNGBTV7miQ8P4l@ZtaxQjcWXEfOVh55qExKNpLJTxq@jLzH7DnvjaAMzxdfTkR81v9PW9DgHlgFA/GtfGx0TGvbgm7NSJMVp3uqkhnyOLIsIOTUubClZ@VyPFc0@bk2PXeWs2MCrIJAqP4zTgjdjTfrpJbDqXXiy56pNwKtzbAWdDc6z@TZw7rzsayobxsNe/jd@2ElhxGIBQ7TZuwzFF3see3oacKTL9KXow/H8gTebA36QdJ0FPqGWFyX4TJRmq0Iq2r0yU8NYcNFinGwk17UfvEzBf7IG5ijumT2/uODwUJNCjMzEP3nNgcDc3hwBgchg27Pkbu6Rd@bR1epFxdXWck/Tb18Oc0muFWSpm4ObXzj1WuzxztoIfrnLF1mQ1uE9V1QvZuF3wrKct09RWXj2OMgLONR7yxSdsAIknPHPplXitTnNWSc8yIwd0MJK14HTimCJSS7/ce2r3RFlB5CnZr0@@DKEI9Bbwme0np5McKHHPTccky/XEJxwnioxM2CZj8dFBnRfsiNkLAOdxh40hyDg5vsUC0RPoHMyaQFO5x@wogkYSr8MkEhfi1i0QaXlZvY2xZ8skODTG/rQvecMCsWqZEgWJG9YY9uFnSDwzHAb9gnrtTwjl3rd1W1is@OR44MF3EY2JWULXR3bN9mAwItXRR78JRy@cuAX1Thsdgn50M9IRvrSehSNtkTBKPzUDtUl277zMSD4uRi0KSW@ALwvzB3fpOoCHKIML7/JrKkfMa3h0yxgdw7vlssptJm82iSYcuM9E3FRruEqFSwlBdVB9wBQMo3hzwT6b3A7OHeLpdzsY/Yq1HypQvxN04th9CyTbAmWQGn2Ogm6PpevDQcQWDRoKWEBiSpTFkBY7qtIa/Vyzk/ZryiTx44ju5578/nZiJjXeUtRQwri6dWK@tTwNJqi0ooPn43D68soqozJvw/Xl3s0Yx9Onj61V5qwfi5SKKBHVx0Z1xDeRm/G39/imjfzVxxFmDz3BGbdWQYEwdFacq87KOcYPPgXvwmDUsW2ipMl0/CHMb7z1GfSZF43pUAfGtv1xFExoB9AuhndFhtHK/WVw1W/tDHr@ZTgIfdqnIWXWnUg8fJ3wVwzY5WhwG3HiWLkpwSrUmSTf@cRaByrid3wuuWEFr0XjYJiz3RTGo0kNqcWxi@HQTByixusV8/dwOoowrvNsNamUOKgAjwL745XdjXvrPi3Pqywn@gCgBdzWlAcFhz4GyGNRNS0Nhrkpzz4UuHiogIXjhcor373HYy@F8fdEIj6GSWFskJlxS7A7gZ3ZvRg3O3deh6N0R4Mxya3dALlIoxw/9nxc00VS5Ad4ClRUeb1kVZVTlDtE6uLL5H5yrzz/B2NPCPwJ9MtP53HLPEZgEdfVs4FkMm8mdBw@4cLugSHLaJbEJMXCS1qFeimgrbtpqOnXk/uowZ4/pBTpQNQZrsSMzNHGB/nNcy0SOa2Ji0VlSS25HPwJFaQ2zpXuZ9jga/6zPPlxiCuWMwimHQ05ZyF9H6naRCVc/DPlXmujLFlHvj5jVla@ddSmCFid53Jm3YiVyxjNhSNQQllfcaw1GJEwzkxRT7t6LEXjwXDpG6l3r@yYG7s4j9Zt1/2qI7AwW5UWyycdJm11gq@TDWcanymmSVOMPc2Ih7B95e8xm08T8a7awnyrtiZfocN9NEv8puJFJR7vjsx9LIof4NFrFpp4SjHuCOPfiJ83W9Tx1v0SRMOU7VWLJUYLIqM1ka8WqCkyxVT6dgox92ncp@jRIcqh3Q7Rzh6fe4k67SRnkgKYV6kwcNATqY0QtElyadiF80XONedTsZCKFc47b8JHeeX8BdJw4IUAhFYc5BM7lFhwk8Ga4iPOn9XNteAtVIYkom9btodDnBYrJhjnrdLGHe3x0Jrky@cbAukuhkS7Ci71ECT9CMWarTuGMkMKmuJzSBH3aEY2XX17r/5sX6gcQZDa/Fp7@pY8dMZVy4QN/bFfte6gAydN6ZqpGZWeCC0WDTQXaJdy2QtkuwrtLxwJx8O7QU8j2kDI4xw@lnUNJLxZK8XURpW7zgRFXE1umW0urqzhKglDyW@QX09FUXV540oAAsGY6lfLBAGB/4w9DgV6QXec4rwUonqMqGK1jGlJDzlvQOLnOec9iKoLPFu1SpTmlfjehpGfC4QUi/llEkRIZ5lfJIFCC91cXKwSz@f3JylBCrHhfaE4DYUelTQN45ETAvLNRCU3kSjNsvJKmoP55bNVN/Uy5m9@@33Jeluafkv0iTFs5svTb9dLqbepZldW0lVTNYkert1q6iWRwrURjqXCn/vHoSl2UqDYJ9TaZKS0DO2fjZujaJdJ@7bCL5Ha5KBso2MYeHZkuNl@tSQJYSpt0cMpitQSHxkgu9Gf7q3xTDWY6GxaS2d9Tp4kxl3ZELLGmsFSj25hp8veFDCcmAQFZk876Kq3J3t79iYY0cPa0eg6GK2WSiUw8YWdHsr4VsOUFA6K6dLF7k2vVxze/mX09qLIsh83Y/aiQcXsoAMaEpoUUWEwupTcacCBiqJ0XgeyYq9/0@3aScpwQonBo2GTkjobguIFKIydXt6eSNLkvWSB/RkdRP9@VvHsu/VF0dRQzDEU1YZL8IeMOT0j8uBBF/7Z8UkVA4NgNt5MtG651a1PWEGQ@48HixN8uJ8S9@TMq6DXG3jqHa6eQaaAhS/TFfb27AolKYITRo7uvUF67Ih0suBD2LPiilHE5nWAMwuTycRmMiche9RRcFm/G@YyzZ8ytKxQl5fRzWVkcPFU5jLj6nRK3wBW@JDQ/qbS1/4w12Y6TRempV7P4OQbYfS07M3d@6SKuGwT0zT7emkQdT66BU7WQF13WRcw2Z54eLkn9xSPiZs5uyt3QcOSwNA4EQP3vq0GQs3@cWLxw7jb/TapyImyZGB/l0SUXIF/TiDyGQDPQD39iJ7ImPnXPE3rvamEIqLgIJ3drNxBhRYqOM7jdvW321ytVlOLw@VlVatt0xdc3rBdU7t4sL2tdpEZH7@/q66srm6IzN11P9HDbfPwi9omGGzhXG5fjXbpJ72rIm4M3toY4sViddHbWGxVN7c2omKzto2wfvr27//y3//9X/9HsaZ//C/82OYfzZ/iQoVCobjY/rT43ZcN/G7uni8tXjQXh@dLlxvgMiJD7WY8aIzzfuI@WhhdOFlZBayn7Edq9tmcfUZXVSbl9bU/@pWkS0Vl21Exq59GkluVZWy2HVjPA8RRXtAW3qTlmt7KO0h7fO1PYI6n0WkHcMCj9YYoSbjAD1Tqy9mKMdwjHUxcID5VyepMPKyzfggQ05JkUkAsLq1Y@bAfBX1YwD@wzivdcxyfPsNxS/Nv8Sd9v/OTs5x6UlJPPPUkk@EP3PX85MxdLIaIzpVi8S3QydEC3AxVFLKix/sHzkY5RW7HWeSkloBk0lRwYYmC8@LdHwfLSEri6NJZwO0ESkwkfMiEKtlPi/0vNCyfqMSXTCrUhhWFlt7FcGPWiUo8vlCB/EgcAZKWr4UglQE1iZM@jkjGt6J5osfa4XybDBhkPXq5x/MeD2gtWuxrn@fUXgqJQNl9Xp5ibdyQYGhGG2@k/QQBPlCR7WSJIwmXskuOeHlbveRuShS23T/NfOLrMAnGxjddKv1NWUwg3tw24Rb7Oq5FO3LL8YrKhPHxitVUZtr3WzlWleub3jgc6nAFbh0T6lPc2heZSRhRBiRwJCtuZXaGsaHAZIqaGhZJJztRnQG6LjNB36uH6eAW5OTIIkLxpxzN7c9Tc9stcpSIYQfhAUYqduXr@mEv0llX5IK@S390gfzZfA@nCsdybsb2PNyVMIXxoBsjXWDI7HKezGfqSnY48i@vfU9lDwYnI3/SoGWLNJ9xu@BSD5GCCUhg8umm53XPICw90kPCFIm7wp5DyMjbm@gEwjK2mTjmBENqpoJOu4JJkGInpmTwOTVWU3RMuPp3DIKN8ozwjk8jtYhlyQtPIw0pY4fN8DSbmTqOacGeO/HEyTiCajwzDS/oSjdYaK/54JckeQ85AnTbGR0FqEMR1r5H@1idLoO@n1qchj3HBPoXN5Ssi5jPnKxdvJEcDeV5OckJDaxIj/wpnQVC1iaTzshZyOUWziKd8DhrryNQnguxL37RV2GcoplT/HJkiDrthyIsp1aoUGhPTFhQDfb8Jwjdnn9J@E1u/QlY8Syb@@FR0W3@dNY/f5I7638@@@gyJlokm1U2r7L6MNtILD1XaGUseqmfxistIhJwAqezfrrAWV9JDItFAkKkmGv@VDz/XCSEzrKu@6R4lhWCpIYMmBQfbq8I8MUZNLNpLIpZZ8F94prBz/1QdhWtrfyJMZQHrnwSFmZTyWZ62ueMugSK43T5xmds7IrrK6VnK@VntBO6DO7yo@AG620@urkI7kiViLCdpaXn7GOKG1KE@HIX@Rv08I76GV72cecnj2ikg5S0CNXTnNtxYraiOgXhCSpPVM6BBAhxceMyPg4fseH3FLGcKcu5oMR10OK@HNbPaHCNdvwIcm06OkQ4El4G4iPCJtQ8IGvGu5dDXTNdljjOqaB2rgIaZACh4S1mrdWiP@jntbLmFpY2oEQjaqaH@xqn5@jMFE3N0EWtTC09UuWtH57/2/88/C07zm6tFN@N6HOc/S27tp6Vr/SFfj01vz5kt7KbKLb2JTsp0h6Yvj7/t/9N9bf@QnDwZrJJf7ZWDay1SXYrX@Uqn7Nba/SlvLJC7f6ff/5n6sOi7NhwW8Fiy1OM2IahyI7fZ96l96qBXsq2dCkRKxyYBRjiYUh7c/oBx6i7lfUSm@my2qviQ6AzXxl/FL3Es2PWmF2FxJJh/ClIM5IKVTSQF5DGhaKrLN8N47YB5k3QVD8/LqxFtAP4WbtzxE3GrhuPI7gMLcq2iAYwJy3Sfl6@bJV@yMTuHZWM8SnZMCoktnZa1q4/3SB2eDMIxmE77SVhput1278NLgrgw0LQuaE9VT/qDX4ZFT8QS16XV9aLXRj3i@zHXRwypPxwUvhIiqDOME8bQ3Y69dSIRmBwjRReHuedJ4V@Lz6TMhnXScseBm2xYaVv7aAiEuPnyfEwulNIVOkc/yUFHrnldap0K5vwWZ9qHh5VVGY5LijleM/rAps37ByrU2DkxRuWbyUkBYb7AOug6U@hNrrkICSuNSIIUqTgdzotX7/LOQsZk0zYcxaugt6wmmHfMOrN6IZdizX9Rc28F0o@hAUhn2dBB1jXwdinLXo1w0@wH09aQJoUfdYap4pLyNrVZfWuvlPd42DV@5u@laZvaUShJSTtxDxjZWNTdjGRLVWYKkdBC0dqcxum1iJzrcmowB/AIJJhaXQRlqC7wxGQRLWkO9qrzB42j/fCxCO3gcTsiWlR7nZxsknwo2dKSAQ1dCe0W5DGSEAcDPpBBR7K9PtYIiCqJhF/2Hckn9/Ua5PfQ4PhPhwOg34qbZ0kH5VlqU/rISsciKVURAKdV9b2wXZk9YhBxym24ksaMjC8ZFywVLfCmy0uaIajwhelmJRQmYzYqZptFV/A0NX3O3AKBTzIlMorT5@trj1f/x55gBd0b@eDQaUCdgHDK59gsEado002nlermaWMPMIlLbNNAvo8sDiAg1vXrctYyddH1XJJAytlGNYtXzYi1bW5kkEmEEdBASsC7VFyo0wu90OliY6dn3Xcz/Q/8bfJD8gMZ9LR@kJ6axzeJJmpnGtJOFBlwcxJcXK4K5mWEHljlw0G3SNkmwjg6ypsTw3tIwPE@Go0uLm8srmjoFNbndCEIYKPR5MK76BeBuMkwZiFFXRRbXBoWNEXVQOvOdsDOOViSYDOJ8Bpmum8lb72NMXsWKJFCJk1EbGKI0TLddRmZ@bO/kDVD3anEdO323D@VoFbsD1bSbnjTGZIIIPbLKzunhB1dbYLDiXVMslLZVVmAVdCuTKHw/uIlW7jqhaLKkZWs94wzj1EljLzYpLaNKlK4wi85sAsl75OShPXanoBghhBqK1JsRDz4vMcm2QJTvYgY56ClzMVy0f0dRhFnGBON5ZxtUcpF6KBjORUYh5A2G1KGelIqYIR5a91vppERhvpziUqGqYB7YYc71SDuSXDrjYVcNS4ZIuPaYH@Nw52PLVbpz9773Y9KMrbtb@i3/ElKPfjW9b4liuqsWeGwM4Wyz638Jn6DSFKxCwlnTA2QRDClw0bqBdnDag39jTtZVI3U3P7POEKsKuvlXBjHdWTBIle2AayoDfvcSoODtfhZxUxXs1Kmjilip4WYuJ6eGJbNFlIWo0hCSm/AcTKNIg4UUvC7QsJw4sHOmvevt67GMZu7M3n6RTLyoaK1Pa9IpE9zbP3UuYhtljRbLFSwTg@xBfMtw/yxkXQHehYtJg5vsIbj/4Yb@S/nTny/18wR/0fwx1PNXc8rUD2CHfEacM5opMvKhrM4ZiLCa/BrU54GcI@1LV@ohMlzwLAAg8YIoaUXpZL6Ns94kTl5r9Ynl6P4CS0srrm/MHOP9Odf1aBzOWvu8H/q53P/507v6o7v1rBWjNn5LVqZ6Vb//v0OFEJc@kHc4cX6q4Uc/9oT9d0T9cqWE3nDPN/eU/z/0k9fa57@ryCjAly4CDp6x/mZtFEasc7jUbiblEwt0rmcNPTfK50sffqVDO0eej2bqKrKrR19YfxX9f4r0Ma8bcjkNW3YpTjvbxsTyVYXjRLtnIoBFlJT6S/JjO61V@9YCX7Eb1AiZBmw9ZIb1RIIffkZXLaVEj0x0T6xovPt@Issp3zH0rCVWsDLTvCsptMcdF8ubC5VG9BGBk5kNXOydH@8n8TMlz7v@ooNEIeQ3sb9HpmJbG3YCdx1indGas7gH2s9xwpVtHkZGTHOto7ZpeF@6UaJ7aYWhfnbxLkqE2uwESWSPtmATYZEW0Kur7ZVcE112wv5An1XQrN77Lu8R/i0u81l35fUUd6Y3AfqXxt8NO8mOzTVlZXH1oDpFYBH5iAJY/KPzCr/iM5XJh1/6h1QZ3W6yCKsg37Chrr7lUpo1BGpcvUbqjMqKJ2/KB/Af@Dt3HyqRXHukGTNiuR4@y83j2G7cK/aHeC7uVV@Muv1/3B8LdRNL75cHs3@VjOOI65cDnnyk1UxvtGmylm7@DMjDJTF3HmrZs4ExAwzC@J1SRtCFkql5fcZqWycu4qzM9rycck5wMJAFZR@1HPp8FjN4s41TkPpXgwTMf2Rnz0H40Rc04ky/X864uOr@4qCv7X@bKn4A2mn7aJkEQitsPk2iQ9h67ryh1HImqXbMiVJc/@aXd1dHndEPucymQ0SvSzwQcCMLbERWMLTZNNLufqCTGfvAk7aUuJ2GTimjr9LV8MIny68uzcrRCZ3vEbMPyV3xvLiWDuoxt7wgTjOJIAS@eOCDmsIiU3FbhgIb3JC2DcMVczR3LKJf215GrqvdVODKOZgD9PFU7RyvqxTFM/Dt0hYDQVBtuDQW8f42ta8DQ1PLWedCbJVoyw5ld@rxuPgrmBMhSnyhTvpPvI9wKC2qmBmSKEJkY3lnRJMPUVmh1oS3FcH4cN13JnWDieAWXji0ozBWa4hGVoKqcPLxrT9WR4o7FcETunEwlzNmMk@N7PhN@s51n14@ERX0ozCmHYEmtbmdooBAWan5fs8D920xeGpRIV6cm1skrzKobMM8ydQW5@n@5DOTf7kPa9@iEaYLmDDoxvB3EXsJpdcnbDryP9DSg/MJ1THCpgwd57tBzF7G2YurymlbqlJSCt9cd50y7N3WDtEXyMc@tTg23ogOm1BnKZB@eirySv1zHOyDlGa8DIF3eyrDodhyTEJ4lPMys37DBma1mchEiAyX3L0xO4feWpC/1D59fRmFrCA7Thu5ev3OTy2Hs6Z4A1xR1jWT3HmTszRAyRFDhOJ@3Ok4hoLP5ZVCvu/d2lUuhnNKtYTnU5Najzuzu4sREofbWfSXnzjdYQW47PECI8T7PALAQjarXrMNYG/WqWs3Ek1Woh90@rxalWWi3oD63WkrQiysT/BQ)

[English spec](https://github.com/buttercrab/hyeo-ung-lang/issues/78#issuecomment-1709482766), [list of interpreters.](https://github.com/20chan/awesome-hyeong)

Hyeo-ung code:

```
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
```

`Dionyza,` fixes SPL, `D` fixes cockfuck, space is for SPL/css-script.

Code explanation:

```
H = Hangul count
D = dot count
current stack is stack 3 during all operations except last one

                     stack 3
혀어엉 . . . . .　    [15]         (H=3, D=5) Push H*D to current stack 
혀어어엉 . . . .      [15 16]      (H=4, D=4) Push H*D to current stack 
형 . . . . .　　　    [15 16 5]    (H=1, D=5) Push H*D to current stack 
흑 . . .　　　        [15 16 5 5]  (H=1, D=3) Pop one item from current stack, push it to current stack, push it H times to stack D, switch to stack D
하아앗 . . .　        [15 400]     (H=3, D=3) Pop H items from current stack, multiply them, push result to stack D

흐읏 . . .　　        [-15 -400 -415]  (H=2, D=3) Switch the sign of top H items in current stack and push the sum of these items to stack D

흑 .　　　                         (H=1, D=1) Pop one item from current stack, push it to current stack, push it H times to stack D (push to stack 1 => print), switch to stack D (stack 1)
흣　　　                           (H=1, D=?) Pop current stack (stack 1) (during sign switch) => exit
```

`push 4; dup` vs `push 16` doesn't save any bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## 416. HTML+JS ([Navigator 9](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/netscape-9-0-0-6)), 18086 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,















































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlpstd[*u""]!!48 在ｕ2\0C0+---42ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#posHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyckCa^ x  \;n
 ; ;:
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({40d71a26-473c-4bd1-a805-9f353ba91bf6}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKpIisSTb1KkpFKpbul2PdQq1b3Xl2SxQBAkUQIBFgBKZEms6O6Z7XWPPTOenm5Pu/247fZ6tr2eiPFOzKzbO/ZMhL0fJxzzyT@g/NjYsB3uf9B7TiYAghIp1W3bG44FCSCRefJk5smTJ8/JTCS6mjf8yU8SeJAjx5oNLMcnvuH5pOeaZ4YrknszsquZXkHNcRxC7bmDyciwfa/KJYhCiKXZg4k2MEjftHzDzRLPMEjXsJxzCFcJ2Z7YE8/oNeApR4htnJNDWzd7gIH4zqlhm28MF8LyhNw3rMvRpU90ZzTS7J5Hxq5p@zS0QMiRBg/9iX5KtK7nu5rum44NQcWlJEoEouunFI5GHrsGQ1Em5LHjegZgdXTD8xz0rICn5prOo70nH16BV2TyoQYZGVvG9EqSikI@MQ23dzWGSj4@efDgqm@OfFlwbPLgepaUPNmb@M6hfxV/gewNDFsjqlgR1auBRSCgb1hluSxfDSpBHRq@qV9Np0z2@n3TNshjKPhSIIQ@MF2obi2oVqJrNlQfVu4WMUZjf0YExhCaZUWV7RHNIxNvolkUzp6MuoYbAnq@5vqmPSDnpj8k/tD0ongU2htruiH0DMscmb7RI5YJkZx@gAVQ2z1yaszOHRd4IMDp2NYMIhq62TcxSpgPQIhHyh8aDM9ImwEH2D5wC9GIB9mwjBBbmksA/H2jOxkQZ@KPJz6BvPVMT@tagLQ7Iz2jr00sP0u6EAY1QP3Ph4YdcDegEwHFicNy9WpCs2YsGoHW6xEZGBvycWoQE6hGs1UluRz4E8cFqgFUmKMAGWV0VkZjChUKVdR3qqQgyxB@EPlgbjXLc4LMLGcNA21ovLTOEO@R6wxcbQTU6BmUph8fHhFPd1x4ghNhWQO7CY2u@WR7myQPntxPkkZULaLb5aIqqpMLqIJEGEjONGsCHBKvCQfqx41ic1hlyY1klSSBLKpM8nmSh3ZcJmoBiKTIFXCAQFBzCpxFopZJXoHmVSA5AM6p0MiLEFKWk1lMt@9qA9MyGNYBYi1hKwFwFa5ynuSgAeSKOQY9cKw@A9VpBkokVybFEikVSAmuFVJRIQeYXJ4olQKcRTgBYwWyB4jUHGRWVhmyRXsA/kUe3Cd9bWRasyAFmoROCgopAVYohwLY1TJggXsuh2cOzjJiWz7iuP0h1MJQOwP0gmWeoggzIimGVSvBTdrakqjoRNnMkveGmDyQFIhZKJMSJF8EiuQhC0BxtQzJFwIaekPDsoJoQw@j0dyWZDgh5yWgRRlqRQaaykjUEpzwDEJSBWmoguhTQZqpIIFUFdw5TALgsJqKUMXFPEtmqHmnkBBLR@3RCgDRD2gUpDhKPgWJBBig1giQGqo/DwySQwYp5AjkH/JSKhIQfmWFlPOkXCJAz4pMoH4UyBdyjwJCV4H8KIgM@EABRlAgTwpQWwGkSq5AuBixlRyGQ9wcxAXSKHmIkwc3VJxSxBPiAXcokKQCaapqZcGckDe1AOUt5CjXqkWo3RKEAd1UyKsKLAWsCieEY9wy0LCMTF1KZhkhNKQD1Ao2A@BFIEYB8kPxAiy41VLAvJo1HmpdFPEsZrePUYvYPIpIRogqY/HgnkdqQlZkQIOtAbKvAgfkaCuCez5K3lIASRPRGz2TCm4L@wololApSxnylTb2F2RTijRH45k/jPxU5ueAQDVBKBoDTZ9FgdAKs1HgwreYQ1@VyuAFIjmPvh5IXGfiWQskkSOv0qSMM9Na@JWpX8/Qen3TG75d5DVPE@kamm@bp4tUCoVsjKhaLKCIAUtepVwc1jcF6MYGQ3QtyqKWEGbsRBW0lGVFodnrGv2JPTCESjmWPxriT1wfOpxFmhXm7ZqDAfTVCzxKlhaTdqAL7wLNoZXL@VzkidTFNF0TuvW7RB@CFhIFVhj@SmWBI6cijpnWxd5eAHUNeocK9md9c0q6d3XamywymKN00ofmOASurgWOVS5NZFouxniDUu5NWY7EMx5t8ZVj2qkkSaa5OQd9EFNB4z04dHSfYO@F/TGyLvS3DtUmFuIzZYc9ZhqIttz5Q29soU7UNXQNe2bspwzaz4Z4TF8kkAjojoZzhvot7SyXkvFoh9p1UZ0F7adnuC5BWNCBvSzter1J1zNeT1C/WuSrD325AV1@XzOtKAO0H9F8qhjAPelBerPlbPddZ0Q7mxF2rZbjjNeoMdCRnyOih865scj6op/XxmMLtCnwN5gyB5k516hiTrX4eKosQxAJ40GFA0KaFGghpmvolPZB0SF2DvSV5SxWidq4m0Ms92JqVg4aC6ggHsaxJ5ZVBf3H0EmuIfWMMwl9mCq2rIJhHkLlDFSsAEVXAwUbc05zEWG6q4pU7TsJa9ZzRstFY/3rYVT0oYkKk3WuzaD2@tC1GlNtBGYAQV0bWi4ZAcewGsSaAMsDi3VIeo6d9CMs5y4ot1DoqCRUgUaa@ObIADPJgShY43maaezdac66M2BlSq28SO0ilpMrhBK5q4RiHvmYB2ssoAb2JjpSDdM2bcpBoC55qPu7ICqZH@e7pNXS4HRBzxsHpqCIDgR8hlmLGQ4ea@2BRq5TjKi7GrYHtognEhMNNeD8gdMHZjs3oewgsCDqArdOiYAkiLymoi5ylOTIQKNTi5hEH48J@EOnBOz5QC6Dauq8MskbCLSGYFroE9edkekYasIcAZSvO/0@cO8bYzwEFGTUI/pMh@YJlUy5xxva2pjrOVTM6OPlwi6eNg2AsdFk2T/6WTIwgPigzvbR0kTGXxRjPKYFoQTRbKbq2hrQCwuij2eUOFxiEaPvOCL69xzDoyzjuKeRAMDEPGNAGwi0tv5CJI1QdQdetanJ0QP5EzQyxI8JcisLg0kFvPChYUMD0oE3oelDJWLN7pE@2OQxRRatEE3XjbEfcItDhZppx6yBpw/QGqC@QoBM9Ibc5i7ZvsI7ABrxT0yjResIsz4OjBQNJW5g@AtU/YgMUiZfrNm15AHi7Erq/EuEWcrBS35NHsa0YaBpREXFxEeBgjLS1IcoEX2UOVTrhjbnTq4XH/ziybsjIvSjtDE3CggfTpQiL8zHehwCnNZ1ROLYQlyNJQ8EXfK4BbXmjVZgdqJMWr24ryhpIojG25COHNtZgRWIGeFFkOUQWheUGZ@h7NCsiBlpc/GW6gjF9mIsCrsz6EnHY8eFlsFEz4yOM9Aqi3FXYJ6noh4jLZJ7yx0sdBxJ7PZ97AshwtjSgBewiWFLBftKA3kBooyZzyD5HJZiLMO01VNcQf7OaQfAmAl6VNs20ETT3BlDAsWDThoSmhHTdUEYnmFXwXqisEsRKZ9Cz6D1eihfkRy03V9NXESO3p90zelVG11HT/GVx51pLumjee6C6gGNKJXse8l0jfrTmLEgXnLGvkSjsisPgBRIhCpP9cHih67iAQiaZzNbT/FLTYzPEn7i98t8GhwYkWlq5CMwGK7mDo0IZJrRKbRr@lQjA@jEBQGuAvrRnGCAJGKA5oK2AY0QbM1KpdfVyCVID5cI031mkISGiSLmo7QMuxelFRAC8xIvr8iS8FydOoRY34YlQHBactpJLBHwPSlBI/LgIUlBD4seVOdjYVS7YZ4Tmw7hkRRTSNLkIlKBoQNI0cyYoIKYuul3AqXl7t1Qfdmo14HZQKcCsdlLx@3acKxTBEkNwCLVSYJERN955mPbSKWhvAg8Z7kB5Qk4td4gF/7QhRZHn@ccAAFZORs5OSRsUM9PzNNJ72pF2@iJQDy2OlCdTN3naxyoAKw11G@ianKJqmD7JpGqyLwYn6K@xrzUFyuUD8Bcw0MluB5kJVbDKcxBwKsrScSiBn4Lht6f6VagEjAXNHYmjbqQ/dNgmCsSRNlAJwgb7bWWypBgc2B4yNHeycN60BZZoNQ17eqSh@XomkW9NxGcD@M@Orx3vHf8s50VOCyzW73qIZn5chG72slUGNgTKS@q1c04jgXi@52bcWPEZRieC4KJ4ExjqtJMh85lGpLz6fGXr5IENCEkB00B3HheUWkYDChdXFfzhlc6YTLIZCDJKEoIS4RDEuKMHJh1DNfC/BxN3rzByruaqXHgjzmzJhpDEHpKh3YYT8TAKwpYGNTtsx6RxgVd1LRxjmLhikOG@fkQdeermaEKdYxlPnz64OC4TtEGo2sCBZE8H3Qpze2JwPPWBAzxVTAg/sClk4y4yDhq1TSvKwms60sEXtQtWYMfEKDFIzpEsEZh0bwh5H3/atmor6BHHECfKYaremVcH9K/aEZj@cAuTkfDd1UvSgMWnVXktbLHikKXuy29UDBK@Uq829IXafbiSOmUAfQDod7oQtCpJ6CPuNAiA7U6yP6zR9cy7lElEkwBIcyZZxGRpuVZHFovgkmSnrQPdppjGeInVOLxhE9LUjKcNRB1j5qgMfiDqemn5DS7K2mAhdT39g7V@yFwMHBNxzOo0YAWOfZMbh@nA3UPeMR2LGfgkC2Iw7TDMEFQm9YWc2/g2NdqSENPLGoCZxRB/uLwjTaGvsZ8Q81HGitutLK5Sc32zkFKK8UcEolSiKKSKLz4SjvTgFyLcj87/OwAOhGlIMuRW6YHkCAWh5ILXXrMl3oQARISg/ysLGA003ittYcBQmyqDwsdCLoo4t4ieKUnlZiitBJ@ZZY@cq5R/JUzu8Ja4MNYCxwxkh0@OXp0@OTg8d6nLV8tFJae83KlCISD9LqgC4lDRjdsrVusaWKxEF0C2oaLzQukwAQMlHAuaeK5ILhFBBFZBtZwDZujTX3kDO2kl75amHMMFV7ZOmOhx9j4GGgQEQztnoXGiMsmt7E/R/4Z@v7Yq0oStPLhpCuC0Sq90h1LG0g0HnQMliUpaLocPsXRDW9VDMiMNzNYDDbEBarDjI4jatbIAeOFTpGjaCAphp6OXVnmYAi2MM6jG25ajDiYlkbqgYUAtrIUlY0KYPoEtA3uYT3xjLU/UNQy42tFVvMSH4ItNX@A3egbYDqloLcCUqSvPJLW3dZdMgMpjZiuIkkQcYsOcngE@wKLgCJJx07Rzg@JQ6UFjpqirKA0ej3BMV2QUlJBzpeUYkECswzMNNBZBRx5E0aarw8F3xEAn@D06bhBjAv7nq7ZfXErcISZBb3vDhQ113zRatltUNBbd2necFa6OWs3lXa6Rq5H2Qrg0zXg3qXiIe@GHsC71AmsSe9kjTzradfFWU@jratHJH80DvocYUwe74Ei9cYBed0z4m0PI0jxQGlrCVZC4LfSigEhC6NyeEFKSdCgoKcF1pMwXwIovageAueA3IpFIIvRjEhhmvlDkB85ktqnrvR1DRe9c4HUWM4KDg2L4xmIPAqEQlvIYYbCAJrgmGHArCTBBEKNB8OTLAtsRUpMlKHdj03PdJIenaxB1QqHbb0x1CMd9daxo/BwoNKHDjpqfNhRAH9hP0HOjSQO6GseGzaFSMEihDA@mIsRBjo9EA2N29GaDOBDGouOEIDwAtbG8dvhYrgTxx2A2SFBmicc/wAlxqbTGAMoJERmBdljBWEpUZ/lIp3azrmN2LoGKQtd02ezDs7Excl4sxcvG4DnVAYD2GjhYl0LnbXvGjob7mWRaSnADtXIyBg5OJoBCh6VRgYtgsZm/NEc9XDoHFq2LODUJeAXyO4@CFLdYENWwgjtOODqA5L0XWlP@EzShDfQoG5Q77DwsSoOKv0kJMDy@gs6UBMMwlIFyRlRoE/okA8G3gs17oC1kLN4re6MDfuq2cmM0lS6RtdJJJNsNuoiubGxkawmG8ksuHbAtY2uHXRlwLVDXQJ1IZyILhojS10Y2qQx0K@dnDdDzNN0G3lgisrLG3Oc0prVaq6d1ZpKcFfxnoaqAMoDtIA3wJNM1@voTKf5xjlOHoEJESv7PvLOM901xwEJPgKdhD3HmxcfNC/XqKF5fDNFRnUX7FYDtdyUm2w15Va7ddHqZVrzZBZjp2taHUxUkJ9@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@6J/hSicins8@OBzMAEvfec9FRVLeqFfjUMQ64AYg@hktAwtsHKDoMEBQLTQSUfsJGpcJjgydP7B2z4hvb32MPjUF5n5PQmoNoGptuxYQ@y5AD4ybSdkQlkCOO/ObWOHcdnAw3wsG5wiNnt5mhiaXTY6erI0I3xdKfrWHQ06qaoC/iJ62mWxsbBwtC9jx@DufH85FldrMaAJO1sdGPaOBS6OllGz8P45Ced@A1nqDzGmPxmgcd@K1ynimImCChhQNh0cLom8C@j/whXpYJaHgxY0MfIMwCsUEBcqYor7wLPC0Weo/9acy@CUygc01EXubpQVOp/5vf7S9456n0qoAiyFt556s1WrC6Zo/EsFRgQLl9dgokjKlKYaBXrWrgShWPLaYCzFwFlGqDRNa0CTp2I0RTn42hNxNCwwjnOY9BbcB4Pun4LtSuwntBWYEtNDVD1xzhdQwU4TgISHbRh75ouC01uLDBoLrFBmxF0cRIqNtymRIJB@BptSLYTTJ56TLg6bpaN72w32KQ7GncusyslNj2w2QEU241auP5vHRimlExGYBQrzRvEoMWk6wyuFTVaNeLRUX@ORqlxngR2zVSVhda0dNC@TEoeJUOf8K3W9I6sfgoGEi7q3LwrDYwaXXK1hl61MCQZaLLdGRFA70MoNoKuD0HakMx0mZRQPxO771g9gU3XATsRZuhhBQVrJqLFpsGaYsN0w3WmdKEvi4pSNrZE9RreK1XauA4QW9QaIYLGdUEuT7Nnl6QJHd@Z6I0t02@Tueg7nWGwcMu@uvyVaaKuq808LlhyUyd7xx9@3JTbDAM30nAKrsxqcRquogb1GdQlXP8OLlw45Js@1QfowggTy6uIkKkpna2B7AMOlkCNRAkFJcKsXxqXi7L0DTCZUwbm3JuNssRIz8W@pfm@YTOeY/Og68nNJqyCZOo0@Z1g9qNKZDpFBPqpiWGQxRp5dnL/4PhYBM71UskDnEqqQnPU9CGoKesKHVIyXvgqudNLkjsYJ43jBxw0NbBBOkF8YOoaMD1YIZA6SpaB4abAM42zQDp404k3GpHpaQGBcPmX7lMaRchSRhrKRJFVV@b/uc0MriCfVeD4DKUkkDt1twq0NdPixDZfix50N1R7BZDAZIVeo76ZoqJsU0kH6/tGOIcNdhZVHaEEzSYR3oCoA2CetNs1thgBYNEMcwdIXZ6nVUEX29eVsOrr4A2KDcUQRK@/JS@aslBpZzZXoaJr3YJ18qz8MbyIYRm1Z6xMdjNF2/u1hszywCYlmfh@To3qK2@NVMkmc/Bs8JuCh@u3qNChy72Wl20tLwqDRoaihI4JYUFCkZAI3mIIeJaGU8kPlg9Gox6pNLmIiK4iycnlJaUh2VQJpSG4FMIqYx7aoCCYHjlQmkfBGwxxHYG21mBFC7bZFseHxtbylDGGMEVeOruiowpnfDwe0xFN@9ShE0@RqyOLSgH1wij26NS6HhPXxNLLEmiUBwarrsudN@r26WUFAJ1/CWb2qQcd2Q80YlAlNemY3ugg/4qUl1ezLCUbrJalPS24ifD6FkihUqbA/W7XXAcKRMBlauF9BRgIKeRnVcyLSvhKBA7IQH8EgovZMIuiX10IRZboHizrDe7//as9oP/12hlCR4FDoJGjA1031pTQX1tZQVR8oJfVFctG6ieWqVHCUNdtKHXNhSJpVuRYjZquBhAE6P5HOLcR1DjwJl5Ap7yBzVjO2dRkeF@dyKrZPRtEpr4O9srCMJYUnYcC865HicCUINOgkajoYpVgTNlcUMzQRjF2e6bC1VuEMjOr9@HEn7ArqLW3VqI5xvOmthlAygWtqxgSW0h/Q5W72umk5wjj00GkpxZXwC5KTyejBVAHgnnpDjpXF58VkC1MD@/rwBZdm3ROb7dxhWdPvLHQpbZ4jz3RhjC6IQXXYtd1IGbw0mHkWE8106KX9@TEADswSrAsQ8Klr0KMaOYVMltad4Y6yPCLc1m0xAEkTl3PZOTcmjnu8Xh9fLQzafxKZXXsqagzeqwaKZDY8lqBjaXRAgcLbm@pVeiuzJFmCWov5lwrzFetkLgGGk2u0jj4Lgh9IeRGJscOSZ9Ymrtw3cDii3yEkwnrxqWDbuPI1B1QB8ZEKYmKGnYdsQ6Disxwjd4iIVzdTC@xdRjmKjKGb7cIkWu1CHB0H9euruGp9xBobM0orsyNMYnorKOU7pzjuVZ9GIJpyq6re7Q3K3P1HsJJsHRLg358bXewNESIQ5C3MOq56Rn0spqwpysz6uvWSv/lJhAO/sUH825ja8@0HI88o9ebCDRwgQrsupqh47Q0NVugQ@Jx9w0yKFxssahQzRo4VrE8kDS4rK31idtHuR/c31fCRRJKUW6RUKH649hKcF8r108l9/S2CqLvT7q40DbmvKGLXSWmghmY9aUDwwCn71aX7IFcpjFFiQ0ErkkYJ17OtVl4/ym6jnWkDbuO8Yyq06DdYYRKGRy@y1Tsnya1/M2p9d5PKF1DW7qtELHKPbUM6Kzo9VqVElVWvmAMRZbfX0T1rYkxMVYaGk@7rwzcGuAGI@P9MyUHxdgMxutxigDflImg3gSW4XvlGvtpfLpRmGiWqRu3qzLLQm0M2vcYTecjcByh43qMgT0ZL9XqknVmH99MsuE4bNJObyl3GPJF5VD5Fk1pST/3DHreaDExCw9XqtULsiwHCkxs3mXp4SZLKhfFfWWy61LC1GeR8gIW59rcmHN1GpQs8bWQa0WQus6wp8CVimSbtuHP8Pqe0rTrONYXqSkQqvj@sgPWqkDX/N5UY9fUneBtFrIYuvBwwKPbXzdowXqbwLYE@qDRfFOlxyeG3qs2BZz6HOG01PLj6jRwWNLSRt2eRlLdcye9QvVcSgJftMUBIbYE2FqvSAZDIYpYFks3Njmmnjpdw9LYbVrM34SvIuZuxLcsMYL5WpzfZbO6i9n4xBWJNJ4BpcwemChDY2TQxxtUfK2H23gEt7VAUwfPdcFTw9Cl6YGhrwMYmyAUbLwuTSPHNCXfscG48nG1IRopFq5nDXzXid9wQnAlkQ9H2sBgm87cJCYXoxW4oIbZdAvn6nGLKltEo0O0xYYh61kCWtSpMfPC@0qEj2c61OtkdPtY25WWr@MA6Hs09XULaa/3r/bQGdpDY8hWr0dP6xoH8KPPNgm6KeuQ68EQF9SNx0sL7eP0tBzLeh96olxkUtJx@ivzdIAv4uL7Y18IL3vrP7jdOnKn@Ux2oGNtqxkaE@iUPMd3xoZAn9aBWjjKw67rBGg4f/3TDh/daOQDRcL7T4v/VsNyoDn@eExvnbE18eiFRhXo@9O3KU19tjqFLs103IH4xhl1xcBTDJau0Pnv1SKma/r6EF9gZ5xtDJyuPjRvy3SwaYYUjvewx/cyXJEyJhHuo7domUBedyYiv9Tj4c/wdriu0oOhI9azRY4blJVVw3P0FXFhrJ3qHhsKRRep4mhwrDWyF8mr9FX86uuJ6S@QxpYzRWO7bE4CHevyHiysWKtW0Tc1FmI4WHCxlkupho7auGDIoO0o65JdXuoWa2K5HLusy1C8lDRHsSUrX4TcwfIfOjRoxgZtwX@Jv5bWLa3s5OzhZOBdF5hsrL4H@hle1o9Z0BXVsfFq6LM0O7itI7NqSfiqJdw7oHBNjBsnVAo3zqhQOMUSNMeEWwduUHWTtQNoljn22JUI/bXzcMFyJjDEr04WMtrMVlvSQcX0jD6b/0DXbVroyHFxMTLoIIKO0@g4fI7CnCleTHDZzgCEumCRBXAIu05tWbmCaHX1R32m8OkTY6DhcutHpo/rNVdwBWXZVSuPbsX9lYnmmV@ZQMnWMRvuHsHmIN34BgP4tALfY21g6g@XKiLKZEDgYLEnuy2xP3pdr4vzoenhcqbIccOoFLIcY2Lkug4YDSsgrw7aRxtnLBoQexlzJfSqgXVnPMN31mbUddOYuunTIdbgvs5uXLc@7MZMnE9G44kX3FbngS6Yig9Bj06pv3duAnLhNYhWMtQsf/UwdWy8FbSwoFNcONdp45@ZljMgn5VlAkobKGGonK9gnHvQPR/hahzXXsGJNO33nPPEUQ7BZQV7DXVr4KsVtunfPJTj@7gyJ7xjYVjPgS8pSI/wKu5@UQzCyWqKPLpd11@8IH1L/w6c98yZuLqBzmjXk7hZEKRq7IcLkPGlDgd3bTmPW2m6Y0HzAoe1ssnojj3xBXdi39grFG/sFaq481WMDUjqKwePn6fj3EAXbN@mhYZ7oy1ca1cLXGEy0wZFbL0cXYYObYn7bM@mY7pa@JY4e7ixlE7F9X1nlb1zNIMO5L0NJhD@k9F9Q8c5w1vTfuI8dmwHeqMxCMrRscF2Hlha5bE6IkZ7hO/WA316tybzjKJd0wkxbUMbG12oX2vhep@@iCG@r/namq6IDgxS@y9y3corptU13Fd0xC/mXmfSLmfooTGltsV6hmFtUPB1nanEOBi31EaWpmu8sePY7EqlrQw35fHNUgW6Anp5/1lyEdfiL40LrLTPlov69IwtETF6bGuMdWV1ja5jsesNC5Jsky0I0FzT8KRHuNMC9SvmiQDal3ejDCndKEMWphFosmeaR2foV5saC5TK9Aus/xlqru7gNFjguGFpTmx7hFvEdLS8n60a6ALhpyCxNH0SbFx6W7asUXdEL2sNhlhtHhtdfDGoS/cU8bXp9cpkI0PBhgqx5VzRNgShuMJGXSSpI7BG0rd3W0t21DJVzTG9UEm9dq6crtQRbNPQ32g4auZQei0GppfCoczSE@pcM1Ada0Z0CFnS6Pv2K1vS8ro1UGgsQ/CHLtj8kn/T2Ha42cuKyZDJyMAZ5uUpmLWqq@MNaWGd1ZPpkXB1DSHYdxBkSbQHIdMPhb21mieih//Tex9J0Al3ivlwAxQQXbdP30PmJ64d3N6HA48cz@@b06eQb3wFYJ04wWIVIArcWMtA19a6QkDt2ROLjT4MYouuRj1qjgl0p2hBsKi49g3BsM8Euh3d9HqJHPbel7SHOwn7Rk8IdmPAaQbhUfgKWAQW3FfMnsZlI670VCRG2GkxH6z9XEXc81AygL7l@MLYo3dp7B0dPnp6Io49ZWX/tDfEVyOu6XFL2zuoZTk2JPVKc2OTnWwtWs/0fOneM0XYf3QoIsAaerMZDQFuOC23dFs77hnuKCtpa60gDDX81Qriw5PHjzKLtzRJan/oOiMjHQ/ef/Ysi6@ZfPRsZXA89gNoHX1nujb64YGipFew73ObTg2uk54rUlqH6cQAaxSY8SHbHeZW5Up3xkbvZDY2PobOEyW4957JF9cW8ol2Zg6wFZLKWkLRhkoqYjGfji3LBmPbcKP7uvo8NccoLXV6k9ht7VoU1BxykptbrT3cNN1/VYshcrAM4YtFUuTr3Brf01jSvL9rxhRFWUfnZ1of6pUU1lbWMsCqyWHLOXuPeWQjMF6EyEvwgasE89ZF5CVhBKJbwgsOzwee4OyuXQNzE4LIu7iywZ8b9kyzBTqXdZN6UYXYuKLtRpDPjPeYkIqW95zhxukr5/ii9fQkpVNn@paET9xYlP39e4e3RTgOaHkz1IdPnpMjzcOtUG4GjOfYeI8cLzSjVwKOW@E@fGunU3suoFJvxDcYr27PVfJMc3uOPZvePglHX0PFrp1uVRvhwicKZFjm1FzVV@lsXOto9Rqj29Jmb3A4syU9OL5FToDo3Tf@taLIMt0ACe@KzB5vqZmwgZMUurQZ7qoXDzo5jESDjnqLCB7pldboI2OKa1HYaPAqo35l/1a8oe8rpdd3JzeFlW8Iy9@Q3rUw9CQ5UVZuQFi4IYwUxCj4kWOdDx1xX3MNb8UKkJUZuqkglRsKUolJ52DndjqxGLjXq/j43kJwW8mtJ4bv5sdDp2vmb1jFsvz679opD19z6TqXgRO8@MGeVyd8PjFWUu2x9mZ1ABU5pyuDQBoawwl9MeJ68PJMaReUX8MemGy7R3LP8Q/o0w0WWvRW9OpFCeb4/mS8PscgJPE7GVfl@hLgJ2A8O@ceuYcvyC309RWDALhKbrX/OuWWRCOEuOvpw5O9kM2ePpPUWIqLXHx6tOSNr5D6T5/F/FxjOl1n/QrTdcbkypBFqk9O8kvJbjdenK0g1vq3jkDvAMEc3dcqREzqffTsumxAO27oj6ww5CPNXgydLlVYz/Hp@4YrA49mU7qYcmVND9latlVhrn7bQjLomU0T0vakTge3Zup01nHlifEpnYQAfYj4TD9hSINNmIxpfhjmkEZZ21Cd04UWtJTdZ@OhaU9XBo3WxaFrSVOvvNXNYI88s5xz8ijaYWideFBXI9fOjFWUXfvKolDJ3ayO5a7oVuvqhX1SJbitq5J76zS2KzIDV0bcJE0w/rEuPQgfPlbTt8J/9CwEvx1233JwIL9nTka3A1O0mcztgO4N4u8qQvN2MPwCyenQce3bQUN2qlbvGe@ZiY33hhzNdOc98tDt928HOvCc24EeTyzfRONlNegTZ2LhPgKrwg7cwUr/xnaj1RKr4rpA3NzdG7rp9eG4QNKZeGAMmZHwjCIKr0x/yTPkmbgf7jVv2KLtpK/g/cghX8Zd5VeQ4s171tFHD9bBLc/cTHCun74XvHCue0d0PMvd2sjfmAP68D6NzjZHN8Iutv87dB2bPaXXdY@LrQBXpPRQs8xbBVq48kG9ZQ0EdmgsnJzlbpdaoCA8WF9nH8@mC7tzufQW23piVdi@CkQZ6Ho6/CwSLlBXcrHRP7YQzfDWj//R3v8rByNN90JGQy@2ziCcSfbWaQLxoYTlDv3Zk3t7J58cPVoZ@mVt1F0t6cNvh6j3F1vorVVso/FW@q0V6RleBW@ogVJFh1oF3AXjytT8J3uPjlb36UOwbKE@cXPU2Pj0oktO9VxPG1Xyq2vwcfiy6X0QVOhe14U8nBmOMFlDNqayrRhHZFtBgA4R/56Jlw22g2Nbp7ANKzwx/OhMKmWDqEkvf@cvvvsG7vqf2sRdrzfpThsAe3lJNoLdLSCAD/fLCPbzwM1xTXti4IYc7Otffn0TkqnXlUKF7OCH9apEkWma@IHRCtuDNEysSTYvgr0qqlVlTjbqhK/yJNgtJPqkANsWHxDjht5QKCKcKmTTh5DNcKcLQr/zRC4JHaMXdNw3GZ5EKb7nTy3YCwTytHlxdHh08Oxk7@T5s6bcngd7hYSlsG1ILdyR6E6ux0PhA7qB7c8@kkH3qLEgOfpxHxzb98JyEfyu3XLR6ktFWxSK38E4mxe2LUl0uxRJmEP@BJ6lRkNRcQUvhjssMa2gYKecKtu5hG7AAnXEUPM0Tai0KpFXJTzWPA@KFYRf/QwkDcXPh1bxA6KYcPBdA@DSgeP0ghQ9g9x@hCk@2Dt89Pz4gIQZXHDNudnzh/VKgX32gm3hBPXUN@kS8jpJBlGSUFf1evJBEgiTFJOkSje4oZ@cAEYHsJA6uDVOEHuLpDYpfqBgMqoU6b9/VZonRXwVKg2wyTBTSUgWeJ4yysbGBjkBJiH3jw8/PjgmmP@D@9QbSYQoyAnurvHHP@yxjzaFe@CFn051R4GtCbXlOWavilve6AZJ5BU12DerR3AnSLYrDDGm9ANIlPPoQFzsY6ppuhEZF9@nJ9y8ZrG/DtYclQDxmOzjSnTfmuirTtHH6TiOfvoL@P2c7rx7ZUvUNN2lkH0oNtixNkRNWS/8QAxO2OPus9j7mZ6Ju@ZgPfRxM9jlRoJrfOkezCLZw6/K4rdrNfr9McjsxPbZhovBrmsJ4FAxklVZskkzy75WxscAk9sb0Ei6xsC0iWeboED5VfIKOBgnxatsVyVBaCSvRQlRV6lLQJM3Bnht91hParnSu1/8F9KgRsDtg/ubgXsq34Onnw@e@uD@BeZ@ISGDXt9tdpGXeIZwk@qgBCwjXN/8yU/wg9N8alNRTjvuWSZZkGtwUWoFUiB3NluCsNmU67ubGhDSfz1tQXOWtvJnxv1hv3c4kFo8D9pSXpK2Li4ukg@2jswXBVIUeqZafD2dzXPF3OvpPKeUX5@OlWJTfD1t8@V69rTdarbJ0dGnbztv0/z0bPYa@p0UMNj@U17J84lqhVzsFHOJ0wp@oBJKeErewHHaJ/in7je9mFtDd7cPfJvkSaLVwi9E8yUexF6yDX8qKV7CwWRGsyE2xJ3227fppqb5U1AOTHPs9XpwOkOSUtX0MwJN7S40IhZBIi16p0SEozCa9sl0zxgMJgfazJw88HfFklgW1Zhg2n782SfBUfvk@XNCnpPnz98crxFj7UwmJQhN6p6Gno9AP8hOSbWjFRL4ick//tHGPHtx1Nn@46@NJGMDb0/x9s35Y3Q/Uwp3Njbu3LuXz2dVVWXuo8@OfnZvby9/P1s4ahZ28oK8sf1Hf7ixoarbqrTR9jylnWyenn7Kq3KeF//4B8nO0dFXPK@R@7@@@rah4KUElzNSIhU8ckQBJ17LcCqkUCDveyTeJBQ4EjP66yRC/4sNojR2Sv/j209fJ/xEQ5U@ceHuJ14niuUEc4IDnnLh01mikdhGsOI8MZPq9To4S//jP0D8xkeAB0Nm23BpFEJcxVmiIdRplMtEowgORVUh3f/nq1@N5RDkGYiSOm2R4bELArHZ5PMlld9pw7FFj20ONxsTZEkK4Wx/6BsOUcp3lbv4YMID3GwD9242/FYCP7L7dJeIL44z0CdkxI8bG9L9bQEOcSwpitpSlLsgfoU7W/W6AP0Kbba5XOEubgybpr3hwPEdYtz9ZOlIfPL3cqxEU/vk7/M4JvumbrhOlksUN3Zf3m80oLy5Rm6rkaFH0MhoeyuVecfZBVlzMpy4poNf6609wu9ONXi5rPLZbHb3uANRyHSKJBSmU7GDKKDdYi@ZYIfYIcwHm3PgyXgRjgZKgjaJ/Fms8HEBR14mm9BG2i/XwyUO8PiT//Qn3/2Tb9Pfd@n5X3CnNrtn9qUtADqD5tKAY7da1RsNvuHyFy18bgCPydVytSx15q3UVrPRPga19sPLZCGXJM@sWbaDzYa00q0mjd@gyTaC5PG5kVh4N5hPI@4XBDBg6gH3gFIkEZYzVq6IaoRcgeMS4bI2oXnWaAs4OloXmkqx0BZYrOYuVA6vlip8p50QNmcgidR2Qy2oT8lugx1kuOkRB3OTU4thQYL8NhZlW4Qsnhpxr0QjjNZYwHxRuCBPFS7RbEptg/YVjTCjuxvVjXK1WFWlTmP9UVvEwIOCGoZx5CXOEtFRIwEfhvRMRJwZ83sRr4moWkjIwGQp7i1wUFcgNKbT4L/moNWVKyp8LXCpHZ7UgD/UnKAOOrysQGvb7UTK@w4cG/CjfziiR7xuUJ/Am4JcPzZIVdlSc1LhTvFAxa736uEKzUaGSkah3ciIKCEF8QoMB30J0bvd7hu9C5qJpnU1XVN8baJNtZnmdyfdadfXJzp@hJ0coXrXCcjg5pyCU3ZCqohCIldQNhN3sWw5tYLfMwfbpFzOVdRcScmVirmSrJYLuXIlV8rnSiVAmCupuUolr6q5YilXLOeKxVyxgt@MB5giwOQQQ6mQq@S4xNvmBjlm8m1KMuHRytx6PBepRMODOhw8BcGZJkBxwu3KucQ/wNFQVIVsQecowwU0QuokKv1BCfc1c@JlOZIAZe@i/Xar@XaLxGtLCPIMN7Gz284I83kT3LVa8N9uRM4aPZgLitqeZzLbLxqgA71oNDOA8kWAUhQIRSp2GqS9TYOi1ILkgvDtNqhRQma7uV139ukp0qYotAHl9lI2d3cpX@1CzMYmNPl0JrMpCBtNwNMMeiMARu4LygOY2inQVS4ufsqTJPNOsujsbm@DWJlvzxvz5vZ8vr0N/216nQd38J1vX/vT2@JYA7MIb6NIajWlRktqBWKpDc@i1EAfUWqBowF3gGvm1HIbO0JUdMT2P86/mF1cIx/McluEXHOJLbKVwA3KcoktLvHy3ef/G56td5//DiqtBH5GlUtcEMIlpK0KoX70VgHN7bFNHrPDBjee4SP6oEfjMXra7GKjKSxJL0VSFdiXHZRyMS1iT99x@h187VkkLwEUwA4GBrSXUMwSXi0X@U5Gmakksc0XS1Sy/sy1I5lM/pOXaqWUZOY2vrf70vO8x7FcLvIJwDVVVgTlssH2pWYfEviZVcc/@Zl1B5e4rBCkUYowunAJYKOEJIGZyCUa2yNc14nfNRLwA5Vn9U@F53sCfo1D86k9joN1oBXUDw/qlUoD7SRj84g2na37W3BV4H@wAYUgrT6Atvp1fQQ6eKufK6gtNEs/1MA8B5kmdF/j79Eb/JETHX/Hr/FHTt7g79jHH3ncxd/Ja/ztdfF3MsLfvdf4e/wGf88H@Gt9KZdTavzmBSVPRqko880pT8lUg@6s0fqS786q9OMcvLqjgs4ZfB0llctX0onWl9jASTX4lgiutTV0v6bVK7VuXQ1Ag4VCGCKaXvj10xR7tbuqkjQOWOQqBccVcDIbLuCRyVUUx03@@Ftf@1qyXk8KSfpdhTz4CV0E6lIgeISYeZYT/F4d5A8q3fOStd3kl5p0cKpQaTcxsA0BXKJONpVNRbZkXVa6ShccJpFdIg/lodJTqN0mG0SeyTMijxylBy4DfjK4TLlP5AGRbdkGMAgFl9@RfXT14TaAXx8QufAzccFUV5F1AglZqKTST8gpHYwpX3bIh0PH87PjFtckScK/NMAAFxVRFotmG79@0eRfvmxJW221UiYiMrnYab5sJdt8i8e9kNVKnnRnxkbrJQ9aicyzxoA@JOF5YNXXElKrJbEKALLRGp3PO52DJ/c7HQm7xxYxGpndDIj73d06iP/gtpNo1HZaVdp7hD1IQtreaTVyArqLGegbVPAjDw3LsLNS5gseC8Rwb2xQArRfnr8EIyh1jqbQ@RnczkPHJy24dJiRRIOl809asUfqgANhJemTFRiWHJBr2wWzgSx0P/iDNfkP9Tf/cf0fPydpkmq206mL@XaKHmn8pdMX84t5cG2kU6ngIbUNP/SAZ4xyMW@gkwJdgKuZSrfT8znzg2sqvc0QNiCZ7QaNu4CDTiYRJUmTZZfU3@8dkg6OVrJGXvLb265@2apRaZCXKyTBv6wRbTHT0GpNZTkNEivYqF2wyaZ2SYdl0zX6ra7NblNp/9EP6Gb8O2kKVMjXasoWYQ9qXq3V8uFTqVyrlcOHzVSqcv1oyDtKEWynfD6drtXgYSdEK8MjxG2StxlSJy24tu/eZYmU1cvLEGcuX8zIOMNTq4UpFSBZw9N0Jr5BDz18SjeyB2lRSBAUCiQYpE7J9EsYKNaTfJW/ezcVfE56Zy99965akS8vI5/xGLyUJa9Op2e6nQ765y4v@Q5PZwcqBXiWy5eXilzJKEmSdtzUE/xaF6SVEhRyR23QZCsgs9V8CYKDHBS2t4v5RqOYB59iGSJCoZjErpEkn6zxiQtaDKVcYnKMr6E3SUCDhl7Tu5gnaE2SfCGdAhmYBq1ynsCfi@KSdVeFQrqWl@XExZxnwEqlwqDTJF9MlTOV4FffSJMGqEzsh3pfLpPfKm3tggaNP2@66kCJWrsw6sq8fmFU8bNI85oefHEVXwU37t7NVYA0ZTlB7k9wQ4psiwvEcR06JtS@4NLikskMuXOXw/fk3WS1tktrVikXSCJZY55CEsQ6KQONJXWroJSRJpzZxw0eQIXgFGqLbpANTqV3vHAVZqFuoCfYvnHZR/9cDw7SI10ywIMM0PYkJrHoQSzCwulV1yMghx1BaPRI4@IR@RjRwYbcc4Uc49IkeTTRTRz2Onq0t39wklW3BZJQH@ztZ9Vnz@8lFHwsLJ5pcA6fjw/27j99DhGOHh3sPTv48PDjg@dH4O@R88UR9RJhXxH1GTHXiudz8gn3yn2jGYZmTAyjcz6ZnL8mr0yzY0LVWhMomzNwiWd0oEhjbVG8Gpy66WmvXmnumB7k3fe/8e77/@zdb3zr3W98491vfPfHn3/3G3D@EM5vsfu3/n2lgNcff/6vf@vdr/8GeP4XOH8fzh/9@PNf/io76fMfwPnfYn5/EJwxOHZygOvnf/z5t3/w489/4Xtw/lpwfu/6@Ys/Wn1@9@vrT4z37d@6GeZb/wHO32a4Qthv/Trzw/s1@F9ncL/wvXe/9B/Z/4@CHzp/490v/QFegod/@b0/@m/vvvafVbX8R//u3de//e7rX3v39W@@@/o/Vd/98r9T5Pjlt95993f//Pd@@89/71/R/w/p9bff5//ue//yT//3P/0//vT3gvNHcP5HcP3oT/8zNNe/@t3v4//bv/tXv/99/P@vv/lXv/udv/r5/4U6foU5/ubX/j27/sUv/te//NVv/vmPvvqX3/nRX/7K7/75//kL//cv/9e/@J9@5y/@xdfQ81d@9Oe///N/9rVv/NnX/82ffe3zNddv3Hj9/D38P/8H8Hn/fL4Pnvcp1xf1@fynys/fhRqLVIBPgLv/@btf/jlg8F8i5N03foivVMC55v9DVaEwP2RP/z9wqNfLjCEyuOD8zrtvfAtJ9D8DieAf0eub0cNSCHv45uIByPqrKyL98x9//m9@QJ8SRrVBp6WwJy@r5cwWGD1blUrQmwczVhDl55axRQiClL6JEmop7Jso2959/6vvfvBP333/V959/@exDxfylexeVlBume4DwMJ7wCFg8X3gEPBTSL@ToaN4QuZTeNr4tFDO2bZd@/TTT7nOpYTv7uxekk/hRz4ND8KC8N2eICgMQ3982YeAf/PlyzbOEcf8JIUhl1R2D4Jw9Q@kJKh3MjuSorIg41LaZLFIDTxy5VwrlnWp39@qwo/ApVrdusgKOy1QBGnUOWeERVICrBsSUbRsbiunAaCUZ3Ckau/K@UxpS9PAus0g3gxVhbZCBa2QI9NMkOQ0mEdGfwCablHnlLCpgCkNnnJTOt0M/xIhZZIjxGb/GkcyVGuiB37gLHRSRxAvnKqmTq4AyWQWEw1UYyRMWdtiPnQCnqabBwuFzt5lpmCRgwNHxyHoHhgE9XoGI9ZZFuGRFaZRJjQrmUwdyo2xWZxsp4wopvcoFohZzxyTzlZ9yiJmEF8jJEeGQ69jXlH5TLl@HxKsT@8TxIXIKdqXL@uNcn3aQHRvGXUy08w9midEVs9MG2/huU5xQjwucf8tZKVcz2QaZUwQC8mqB41wrKQCLRwtO87@sjqAOy7B2tkl5A6vlHk2x7KBBGPQeM0soBEQwCG8ldkKikP/oZOeW5TgGzSpIBXCwneoqrzDtGcEALyCIIoigRMXNuyQXQieMlQZmizcMgxDhnIE5YDIg1CacBlav4xAkD5406/AElXN18D6qBH0cnUOPw1HV8vI3OYUV0JdkEBTloPvn845DWDyco67uNSClVKbGpmDV5FDCJpmfesLH5hZJNbm5iaXaPA5/imdG85IEnFPq3S9G7RcakdVCV@s8Oht0MV/jHiPcTF4lqPuGhaTvPvqDxJ5uZTgNpP0892EJUTuZNi5u7tF7gBZ6T3mN6XLyoRMzsk7CUbG7UyGVyHRhgNPW5SEGYqNe0ESdfyDf4IyFkmQI801vSyXpSIxCzexnsBg8vTp0yC/1ONFnctAi1NzCj7jvOBkMoHoRg/n4LNZUcyK2WxwF@mdeoiBQ6ShwV3cRNKTuL2nlMr4kVlbHyJduLdv3wJvcEiL6iEY4MxJ6mq@TAMJZYMpLvjSRlmObeZgWbNwXamar3BstIIoxTwhKcoRcKQJLqBMAWunObYKi7FXeKSSahlMaoSEGhNTAMbQFBWUSWylKn2lhxRKS4@Qs/gjjkGycW9cHBAtEWX5S5UL6TBw/ynZf/r48cGTk3G7TTiDft7Y6IxdRzc8L4Vhe0/uM/ZVK8V0otnEsp9UVZSR3EFVRjbOHN4/PnxWJYxiQdWlaDlqdF49oEtF4RLj8SfbCRfH3l2Dx29zOfwzvFYXpEipFZDf6USDS@gGGmXAp/iHs0aOjQGy72NvcM@ZkpSc5fmsUkSTOY3TxJCdn3UmBPeQZBtOgHTA1XwilBdz3rgQYrNP6NEgxyrHHIJCHSRXKYeOEnMopSICPGUft8txjWcHJ4D55ClRVFkkx07XhEw1PiVTkebz2BkZTlaY09gokU7MkYMQVt0y7IE/3MQPCPMtmY8RaLMpZ/Gn5nJwVfLFrFIotTc2rAsB8bQoy1zgWsU5PF4ISJMP4CDcBxz5ALzgEOaEw4@Dk2CQ//BpjTEvvqpLUpD7Z77LKwWQC2kO5ysCfNw4ftSA6NDOlif@uMTGZ5/5pNE4eHJfOHyAAxPTIQkXOgpmTxyKlHF6E9egoQNCeubHJn7GTeyZ3tjSZtCIgV5bDSCIjxOwifl83gechw@I2lDpI4vbw@tcpz5dcM@nGkdAQPe5xN1wLIYr3a1W62@VfAnyVq2@zakqBx7cFmgVZn8DuI0uWtmS2I@363lFzijhTAdJ8zxf8yBTuVxZ2uISCs/DLZfLcbQBEa5qcIQuZXor1@tCIOPzCl3JxOGnBLRpXY2OAHZ6ZwGbkxkshkAAGfgukcOwEgsLnsJuAYqCa3vpl2trgUSR797N4YhULi9HZSeUNGQOVbqZy@ewksAPfNuJfCmYQoPytROcZfikVwd3ooUFZo1ZSfAEn1D@5coyl2gmoGlzzXaz/v/9r93k2tN/vH8gS7NZ56YgIeNn4I0w9E6Wfhz32Hm6@D99Ooo/3vgfPXUeP3VGDvyhJ3yMAry2@NdqS483/wPJiUKpBqow5xtTYCf45eUCPP7Nd7/617/0n/76335TxCN4ijz@5rvfYf6/9q/x@p3v/vV3/tlff@ffUp9f/Otf@1dB0N/82m@S@9DGZ2@0LPeP7ACBQRsFm//dDra@bNC12k2lkm8fQKNrkvZ2uCtmA6C32Xs8BLcjqfNIMsk3g3d7Gp5h9UVcAV3nt8eNnKzy28H@2w3ysWGjUAviN3r1nqPTz5DXeqKJn4PHN1VYvHyerzk2bmhXDydZoedLXwzq5/T95ppRH4i4RYpraxZE7zq9mej5M1BZdMdy3HoSzLckaH0fm44FdCccuPd6jo0alV03QL3Hge2dXC5fhfKJY2e8oxZKAhGaigxqEJ5KOdsDwezuQH9QVbMbxk6pVO2JumVo7k6hWsBgPZoa3ynI1YH46eNHD31/fAw9uOH5O/kKRMBtxnBDoJ1ytVCAtsDzmSZNsY3fU2YdnrCxAR2EofUEuOPMuSeo5XaVpl@vJ5M7OUUVlGpOLnNBYRcEs2u2kFeKO3LVj5ORHFim7bhZnsPPvka1gBU4VBp5Ob8twR1MVgmn8aF7b5A9Y2BgP0xrTtmWxsgT4ARQDZxdcBa2pS44TXBWtiUTnJNGTpG3pQljDawCYvbqkBAWJ4N5zSKPZIfKRdDLVW3HNuZcNatlzQtaXdV@vz/fusgsHjjtQmBPUJFzQct2L6LHmhCDq5JJVjAXgeCj9YEvLoKlClVeLZT5WrO2eC4V@Vp7zu2OjJ6p4Xe6W/LF9VhF0D4Y1gQk1CLcvOo6jl/tGn3HNRaAOaUYArIMXQfI8/MouZaMKV5cT64YA5peXMeSL/DzKFaYLW4@h5pFoiP5Ey9ecImt449zjQaw1kW@pOYL@YKaKxYLJRU0pkq@WChDzcpFuaCq0L7zlXKlNIeGJUlvE/RbdGT/ImxwVbohf0qrsh0lm22SfvvEtC7KOYFJiFS6Bl1s4i2XuHP8sdporB/SSYH2@bEqNOq5QgVcOXSpOdohq6qg5oScIig5/N/iUPH//vAq/FW8Qqycyp3gPjNPQPEDndcmj3CbCt8hJ45DX5S5Z@hrIPaHGt3TZt91PO/vAHNPs09Z0H2Tbe4aBT3U8Jtt3sj0h2sgno9HuEWN4f6DYTgYdSGDKJAZwD24uJbjrAIokedHa0r5ONpOHYjB9lMH8OPDDx@exO4nB3v7D7kiuff0yf0rt0IAVCCPDh6cRI8lFhpGLUQofvbg0aOrj8Et//T5cX/iuHhyD54@zy8ukRe@X8Tl4VgGirwpkuCCj6g3oHpLNsDODB0Kh6823c1XyN3AWSgunDI6P2EvT5le9PYTe/@uyp2Eb1Rp9B3ZrkF0thMRDsDRXQIDU1gpVThuTGznnJRk0nMsS8MP0Pc3wHOoeaRrGGjZWRZyIiZ97rhW79zsGRugb0EaFQU/9o2Z4B4CktFEp@@2g2aNe8728NPwOM3dtSYGmYzJWk@4oRc6XXMwBGXg3AkBuK6mETi/6AHxjfjh3@zhszSo37UQ6zo4l@D2nqLJXknw/D7PP9R8reYapRekcTAFToV2o7mzbDmb4/0CX7UHOC1qjcEIb25NwFLY2MiXyV/86g//9g@/o7bkfRnHcvPqTKsrUq1bJ0rxsrGTd3bRnED7dKtjJMqDetUrFJUd7FDrcmY3MXa8h0a5xvNgpYMMrXpomj9w3F6VHNgmSJAHcPA89pr66b72Aof3WjWb8lyVqmv3HVfXcG0u2nGEWmWBOSfSUQS1Ui6UKzm1nC1XyvmCUiwUsoqaVUrlUgWyJStlpVguVJRsOV8BNStfgdACGPLMGJSkLbJn4eBPlhl80lYV0Ns6fuN6mw5IiMMGl2DLJ8iblJYmCS16nhDegDg82bMHhgU4cBzJpy/2bZl16ImJIpNciQBmjegk8eDBvozlvYcPuKhsX@b5Hj4UyrJcusfzBg3ZL6MmyTssThk3DuR99iDL96AyJwwB7rnP80N8OCjiRADPm/iwv8fo2scHFeMD2CkLYQ9W@FACMBsfwDqlCF5H2ABsj6WTpxk9wAdMEkMesJB9COP5D8PsYMgxA2MIHoYl3dvj@UP2sLeHIfu02AWW0S/jwx49eN6FB2hpPD8Ax8CFNg4cAk5sbzyvg0ufaeCH3xXHbdltX@P5GSMPEojnpxRa0095vhP6YzIfB7kpIHWr9EFhpd6lDxX88bwaZhrBctFDjufz0UMeyvbw4cfa0O8ZA3bMXHbXoaQPH@Y0czo5eND98MPuYNB1Z3sHHx5j0P7@Q1BrZhO3O@gGEbsdOByItf9Q1U5Hs6sHlPqw06lq1sqgL3c6ec2@EtSZdQzMIcR6DTkLjgEmNOrsQ9D@w86utmo5DEXYQVEzgnsXj3sjuN/TuiwoPGgQvU@7Xb4GzQCMjlaKQzsJV7Rg8zwF0W1nR5ruOjV8ntaJTNcNz5pFuV2jAWQEho5cm2N4P4VXDcdq0xez5rQut@vTeilYjtpP8a2pWjD57MZoR6kUqhvajqLmM9MqvpPs9JMkKSg7JKXc3XpDUk/SOyqYOxt8a2dH4JtKe6dYeoGirYqXHVUpV/OyStLsMVeqQhw5KROCl3Sz1N4pFaqLyKVSRpPUaqkEWiDQxwddooujox2SSp0b2mk6jVmnw2tQHlpwMqOFNmv91DQ7rbNMklm6Nq0rNbY3MZGvYEulergR/kTHfQsIQzoAhFOwd3ApVYpXKmUe8iBJqTQIo/l8zohzkZfL84sL7@KiNY9EpQSuxQDnJ185OT05@RSkFSgrsyzVRxvB0OCRa6DMqwWPHz7cFw@fhk@4x734APVkxxX3UcYthTCFOfQ6AetHfAg9PJi7oR/E8V3HEg/ommNQtsOAcGcIMdhvVjx5uITn2dA5ZylDJK9GNy3Et8HxEwBmj2j1Bri0HknRXBEtfU51i06jUe/UR8Zo7M@giGGsLxO6P/4CzaHH8k4/YYL7v9HoF33XGQUBnbo8h/5umpgKAtkD1W/iZgFjp04E5eXI6b1UM3qth98AuFe/h2hqHbh3wWA3XNdxebA3@Vp/x65PbE/rG0eGi6@4Hz7dBJ0Hd4hI9YmR3iStA4TeR1NpLjRcYi/y@GQySmlCo5te9sLh9MgDyZT6Slj8CxxOhpzz/LzWr5PUCwB9Dc/uJkn1xHvpnXwNKHaPdNLgJb/sv@wTlRTzNWoRpRAXNEFKKaSAlq43vgyqGkN9SqpVyE1Q5aeAFRMDxFAbNERLj815Ta9bJCWQaZrSKF8b1JsY/RIv2wKoF4LQvGzjaPgnaCa8nkDn2YDmXpsltLo36dKvyBC5q6hysTYFP6WUrw2hvrUX05pbH09co2bBYzB@TmiJtRrQFkgIaN5cpt793FfT20KhzvxqFNUlqisdsVOf1mzclxI4pZ6rQ0CmmZezhTJoMoVSFlQItZhVitlcNp8VSugL@kO2kAVPsMhANUpZKZ4QPitPZVHJKoaSTckvzd7LdPY0JQMdKPHSWd85sCcjgj5QZcit9BnuWjqjbgGJeg7RtgXKvCBkalguoP2QjM3skGI6NjSLRUgLJLeVsjZTCLR5MhkfNNvV6sF0/BUISgmvd4qZkpx5k07XUhvpume8pnMN90xgEA2Ii5KJFn@8ATwdzDEQbzJqQq2DSymp1Wazi2UtydmcnINimp3LwTbf4NtZeaOoQJ3N6fCZQphkiQ@rg@bELfzGHTQZLAPqUKmoNU7E0ewEuedO6Dh/rqwKFamwVZDZ2DpDwY0DEYm0JakWH7ywkEwlkyU1mVzY1@lkDScxN/jFrBK1uuli01QSRDZJ3lULxR0eFEC@yldUHsAWEhdzSeQw51tkXzM8zcX5Bw7HbEgerPYLbn4x325wU5E7GJmWqWWJber4zTZTPxU5VGKzpGsOSF/zsS2L3B6U9rAqcs/ABDSoq3mAW@kTFp9u7oDR2gHCKp2b8YezoQF2kcjN6FSVL173hVoieA@TWoYgX@Ke4d4A2@oL/JVePN57ir8Huwl8Q4DsfgnCKuBffvH4@dPnTx/Q978XL2h@kWOXIxJ9DWAqdmqJGh1Txvl7SIap9e9/7OLcLZE28BVnkhEFsUFfnt9lqbSCbVykDUK@6HsKme3GC3Zv4VtvgJqj@3g3SZuuHzZMtODJxxoolDskCVWuuaOmqubaTbUEagl0XU2ZgaqqUoNcdBL0fc0G8Pf0AjK9nWngK/JfJrOZlhHCot8ljUFmU1ZnibMOX6zk6PvcnYYin5KN5N0t/OS3QBJnpxsNdSuTPKrmMsn7yVw@cZZqbTYyyiwpka2MOuvjSidcMSMlAU41tu7ktpLPM9XyIFtVMnhV4VpNEmEjsdvJ7qYrHkc5mSSWCLxR2avvDY73giF/srffKKuz4NX@xIsOXy4FWWxtAsnUzIvdpfgN0IVe4MTflXojP8Wxi8ujk7Vk4iJJEsl5ct5MtrnELt2EQGWbEJBEtA0BrlcK5sxz@SJJJ0g6eCpVEl4qTdcQBJPWX0ruJpI4N0w87y0wNa0L2rTDV7q//FIFQZOwndDDmfg4RAuqVKGAM58J6eXY@0wt5x4fPrXvuw8MLtHauNxwcFab1HiGkidv7Y@@QsgYaixJWvXEtJ4P5g6VRkNQtlXcvKlEqqAE9JWiIF82mDRr0ICiCiHvfu57@el2GZ5VWYFnVS1k1EZD2QI1NDF@9/nv@O6MXBx8vPeIJHEm8m//8Adq6W//8DfpguvknM5OqrlSAiDRqRRLiYuL8cUFKIFzFlZItBPXFpi1gUySolVKWyLwglTWwNGREoykoC6XlHTCExLBcvtiQUilFElNb@XKchpCLoMNclKqXIbHcIkA9eKLBT6dODg2C6qyu70DJdvJ5dXaBlSrEu0tQaLftuFVElyi/PjlJSHwoDd6g4GpUpckBe3orUC23wrbcIcafitskJf1Bq6SU3BbinDCeQtfbsflH8lGRtpKErC1SaM5r83bGTppTQdBXmzZrSvEaG3gK5LLXls2/Iwtj/4Mgz5SDw8ewydj65XHp7bSktTr0X4HFwwIQiPBWl3HIIUG8MuWBLncCieZ2U8QWul3P/fLqlr82z/8xcvOZedTVVUrlUpRURM/@cn2xJ54Rq/xE4h4FG5FBkykmz1k1hPn1LA9MRpzoJ2daeMntkw7GqsgbLM6M4gVOUSd5xITG@0xBh@OXOAYBQGd1BzYRo@OWHBnqFHTau2wzb96KQq2RcAgyVJ7ju42lK5xXGjrMHvNHehZioNs4d66zXaau@A@wCDQzwjYfDXugwUq8BiBRuboHc@auGP6ammKxlPaWXIXokAKH@DGahsAnSZBvy2AJIa@@lpUlmWPUo3q3AQ3msZt2kAd4T6AKMFO5NaMjDXXMyikaYOuICIIzScN6DUh7TakbbEIHeqboqVnAFnCcsci2WDGcR@AfkmpYILaScxtAKiBTPkACABlSAWIzTbZJrk0uTAzmdpiD7g57v2BL1lq4SZlHEZDbD0gUxS5hnDgBeYjfvsW@SKoYZB7Mc8QCcPB1n/VwQDF6PQJFXoT2GH63qgA1/kQa4gWjdy9u8hVvW720oSWCPGfmmMcuqX1YK/OKyALLfk7IFJBpcpksLI/WGY7oHiGZhe4TmDb6tViUQmPj3OOg/97My1y5JWqogE1LEBQX6xV6EAyiIxkZ3Wok@06UdRSmkSZ1yHvOs0U3cImGp5oTe@I6qdh4Bxy@JNE@GUpEFYn8eHwgG/vG9bl6DIiuEfACJvQbRP9ocaEQc@wzJEZfMIdhd6hH8aOYkFRTItC900XTGG6zCzc2y2VU9IYbbEXHs0HfaFMzRN8rauQxhuNhdAE7hruNRaks0HVV92BCvXGjk03J/NRNOGLdcARIKMggSeOb7BsT@xz/AxcUDc0cjxHUEqwdJDzMcd0szXHNjwWF9drdV1DOw1pkyXGQCT6qEfUCklRRrNx6YIdoUvTSDTDXbCgkMZdyxhBlp4ZBn3D26tK0gAUv0kXZ7Glxybw1fCBCd2P7Un3GYGlc/PUlE5wG2bB6eOL4BQ5YAFdEZsfW/EFxubE6hHLcU6JZZ4abJYjFd/oDb9AUcyC8ZMFyi5OIGwV1V41l8WBMCXLoOAswa3EnOVsLO5Gapa@fs8pG6kO1ugl7cFMqBXLONPsGH3pcckFgynezOPovnZ1gsZDCp7FSORCy2RbRCVxj6hkWgTa91JpjtavB1EwpoizZ@MUn@DToje2TJ86ubFrnBEcDOGwjwGhqXeCLGArhtJ@QDsA2vagZeFec75bhZrLQE7cXkqHphcIeJvcITmVQ0BIGUFZBgAHVn19GTuEQVQsh@f3oGJEOmWEcgVa56gHYbiXVcB@GD/kbnTTnf8W7E02AnTY6dC06oQ1i/ChEHvA1oH8TIu@AYFFyOGKnGyk@AygzfBpnqGO4l@Nzrido7KkSq5jyhLEEJAasFBVQUORQ7d2XXyvDZd93NM89lEP5Hpg@vPzc5FuqzhxTdHw8BtmnmNrljQemKAOO5JvjMbB16JNXRqHeBcugX26UBwPxztTVGrrlbszdue4vlcPFnCmkn0viZ3jGX6iazA6Q/sKMtz3KEM9MOnn/fRUsJ6U8Z/azl6E/FdF/hPKyTkiIQTRTLOzrJ4FZNmufprtn/dqQcAZbZCAHGrRCD1xs1M3fBh5ocsc9yMIx0c5GgV1rVO6ugAw8WzGYJE0K2EIOQsfg@exieu@beOc7LmuNkvR8DRCIwOnZlTtITPo9mkIOHGf8wu286Y5bc7aS9GnUXTo1KI1QCDIU9hz3YiUbcOK4VMWPoXwKQufLhINk21O20wlQ685Fge5Hhewh5CIZhbCzNmWpYsQihn0cKIwFAg5W/LDha56ncYO6c2eoB7rIWMAT4yB4EZKar5oNVtt2zPOt9oZaQDMzlNCQI0D6mab0vS8F7mR@taZNXa8JS/oPqh6E@QbvfRhwA2MV7CMUQVRxmD0MnGbycEoWJvEFIKgwIAB9TAIRNVgz0@Z6Vq07y8NBMZp8gsas4w1g8y0qfYVBAV@oC4x0jPCxhG1Y4jQPyoSZBNCSNhy2BcrQ@nwiesATAgr0I/sgYickWQ7CZS80lSYrKnRSorlShDCbALZUV2tXy1KGA5V0bwSFCvmPKj/ePY3vnD2@9AuVueeMizrMGpcvKnganVQIYLmQqlKGvVYvUIOpC3NMlzouQ6Yfhr01pDMlhSaGSwdLIJ3bvr6MBWrfD3N6oduLMDbfDVihVm9DkWc1VmzZO0iJCkjeBTNC6LNQkYI4jMBAjjkldGMINo0Hm1arzPBQaZrop3HMjmlmZyyKAx6uiaT7SAaWE@HYfeC1dMG7fT/7e5r19pIljR/U1eRlnCjMqUvbDANiLYAYescDB4@7PYKWl1IJahufbVKGOSP88zMj72B3f97CXsrcw/za69iNt6IzKosSWB395k5@6z7aSRVZUZGRkZGRkZGRMKPPkPwyrKMkho0zKjI/xDAoeOXm94QuyrTZiJzmAs0D0HFBp@1Lua23rCQtoTWFAAw4gyAtlx@veFMC7xyPv4VyyghpZFR8kuzgcgKYjAWwZuO7IFiJuM9MCn8mWVeB2juZpYbTqbMRwX4ryT/Zzzz0Pxfnn1YSpcspx@WvKn//lMeXoCy1gS1tI9y6RkEspNYKrKPijfRiPPiS7rfW8fhUBy1d6TevaqeqtNXNbV/tvtX9f7oTL2rHp4iOuLN2c5BfVfR/7XDkxpHWSX/3tIIYB6veKT1twJO2L9SKj1TDHl3MJyI501u15XnJ6RmvyJ8Ici3Ir/34lp@FPrBeFtq1ZAmGo47IadQJg0fOxLao7YIHCthbXYKw9GrorKXPmkQ0PR6pI90QipLQKhsSKyt/YhI4W@RTkp7Mu3M68nG6NrHPVBX2DbBsanbHdxSdZosXUg3AuOLhYLvd6USXCFoF5QmXPzvd1PwtHb8@kQhMGf36HCvflo/OjxR@0fH9PPN@/rhS6Jn/eT0uL5zhldc8PXRXn2/vlvlB4JAqaAQKvPLDW0dH0KhgOJMldav0A35Gt/4V0oXzTpOf6BufXaPi9TSDX2G45Dk@cegvbTpEC8pccnjyaRyi9Xjl28bpQsV/AYdwChLrKFnziJOOb1YUlvcGk3H7fN@RqY/Z5DKl12esb2JQppvmr681eHvnjLAeZvbDknK7GIX118aKwmRgUFIGdDU0COCDVBmS1dRvwzCfm5pydtikNvUWqs7QIoZaU3MbPoHqr4wm7FNhymmd5MAihPjeh9SrLwZPyC@pwcrutnxSAqop/EDKaCeyYOx/2tQx@5KreoSN@OjGxh81Jo8@KU33GfFST2PH@z4rFata5xk3HhIfXWZXBfRG9L2Ga41vLhy3nKJJkOViMuH2EJ1ZWIEtO0mlifdTRZbtv5QyQzJ0w4ynGvDkNycgLfEDdhJ@50xbZ0rbkGdYvsc9DF7aEJddf2@GAmSzS3znlpHsGpFe9@G/daI8VR8Bj8cMAOqy4lK4xHX25N67eBb61HNnZkWfW1F5BTsxkjzNQR2ZhD4I2AIUN6WF36L89@zxyLADDqalXPRgDgSRoK/2eWJnds3MPVZFbRdI/dL@PGjq4nsJVXCxJLH2NEQfUTCY1nsSZumOc5ilS@9gBRsXQ@G41DGMJfuAQnOQG7toNLURyD4c2U71RroMN1if9C3Gr0kLr6n1Utiym9plTletMtYfCVXABDnh/1ILFNAx7/ENbZJyn5PRSTbAnUVjNVILLP2pQTYyDtOIjv@piLa56xXtvd2zvN/@9m7KBavRCxILn9jlsP/cskBVhL4oYhJj3TksZlpGqgT3VyitrZSaWmJWW6AVWh@hZ2xetHcjN@JQX72OfwSpp/zw8@fK1IrD8mkL46IrnOJdPNUwzTpcZ0LpTdJluwkZEnW58wTj2HG8voFfBAwCptEkT7kCCwGqasTaEKICDG9u7zpkGQRxcwMdwzfVdu850iuF4GDgD0exZ9yO5XlbbeYbLmURc6cEdGegVx2XWvjxuvVDLi9h8GR/P52cOsPYifLw@@CtvcgtN@FW375fliyLFmwvh3s3x4AK4vbHwJLfffuByyL5Cy0mNNj5vQWs7G9@eEWf54ZO557BAZr73AwTIBard30u6R9K5OsLScVXBtMohCdnO7Vjo9Vhh3HNqguyT34grW1GATsR@YWJnZ677OwK8RKk/mXKE/mScrmY/49NJnnEu8eUaF1EE/TIxYWyUU6HdpSsdTTKwurEHw@xQLRUC6N3Scjg6KGBvylUcbGLxk0q4PO3G5mZfEJI/uYRNPNE93YPuXiMwhZu6noeDSxAdm7Zv8KZ6/zx@@d6Mcbph1RsBBQhw63SZOm9Yb2CSe4tp4KFgrpEXxgWMyQ4hhKFOysoR1MI6W0hv3nGYoZSZRw0YUtsa6VY42a6MeLRs1hkx2WAR@2UP1SbP70woh4frJlD6ibLHq59BJESqZLtV/YXEHVL75sxjdp5ZJ1shIr5PZcW2RsGgbLCxxZaNib9xd6jNOCtWnxMN0USdsHm8r/fZqSVSLVkqH53M6YlwR5bXX16ddgT/fCVM//WdiyhkzLz3FvSPv7BGQ0ifikiji3fuiZ9wkDPEA6OXwyE2aqIqk6c9aUVN95MbLxI1zEXELIILdh65rgTrXqqrsp3OZDlxXJhs5FZvpgTeG4ozJrZqj/5eHmIJC/2t6j39@eTDYUgnHtC86tXg9GUZD4rVhBNtYjOBennwWjUZ@LyYl/D1ByfND/oDsK@6OISVh6hZd86mb3pKPP78Uw7RlbAzeiOPP57bU/JjlnsVTilWJ3db9@UFNPOMVGh60P5pA1M8q4lux5FPYfQoBlMNslsHywl8vjaIP@Jxw8A5LIxP4uOaaN@1XcmCKkNTc4obU2nGrZWp4e/U7U8vsIx/AyjyOV8b6jii7YpXa07zrpq@q0W22qPiEXDfs5quVl8oUMV6VnpCjgmZsGIaOJ59aChbNMc3CPA2jcVF/gW1WDO7Ge8UG@Xyyvl9a@d7h3fW/s9RrfX3hPWpWMosXX7/eim9Ft@9erwfWHjuqq4S@Xd63Jx9@UWn2GxGBq5TtJ/FReqxQ5Uc1zhZxh35eYczWCP3ASK1wSVjAukEsq2YdvPlJ81aHiTfMGzhCnuFQ96RkuhBPKuNJrrF1U@pXSZq/Rv9iEG8x4uTJeLi/n8OA7WkVJxqBmrtUYX2BNta2uQf8D3/nHN/How1PFh6f05LU/CgcH1cOXKWscFACYwPRpCMZDDPjOAs7RcDpb6Ae3OW0m8xQ41oGC5CzwuXkZTqZ8yg9zTDskzGhUPNJmozv@O3GdhVLhZjge8BsT6g/WUp/Dz86COegvyaWM7aARmoQAfNFbdJeUyVGRUJ5O5JwhXxZ1rQzvItcC0UBNFoeZ80wGXjdAVHs7NC6cqBD4rWsggSv0Psv9fltbfKEesVpUYCtezsW5NR8pli7wtUtf6WPI7gtogjX3iA9GHeo@fpfxRZ6wjWrMJ8l8hOSwpog3OCBRn9gDgOtvEQGE8AuicxW0iVNrXqRIincNGxcQ1pre@D8iIQDHIxmUBXQWsKW9SgKcz1KYRmhWk4meL/C1hkIr@qd7kC/zr5luxOVdKc4kWUbX9a8ItOQh5Vfb@Ogm1XJWtbypZgpbpFj4KjVg6aLt0euAptVE7QbdLiEttFhIyIGv7AGn21@O248aaPMiRl7e52fe51PvC/JekEpKFWiBTwpt2IUy2U9JuS8qkxTzZtqqKFZeCjTSrQKpJEnZzYfKRoXxoBkmhbfjoRSujF9spV7krTc/zRl9efMoVSdm8Ph9Q95r/l7RIx9jmSr7It0@Ph09QPhj1p9pLi30w@4Pjr68Tr8Bm2WImkpJdb4PRJlJVdFeSlqckAYHOz9P2@1KAmW5bCQOz5nM9taLTEErGT/kptEQP5@ZiTVnjlhU4jaXmXB37NJD7fDrRxYIhglGU2bmbpvKE115YoFFqUemWfETmpng1LXpKV6B59Bn/DGTPY2cKZed/3JBML@Tzov/X5pALHQfZeaTKS1NcKAqD3WnHlhFkrYn0xDnC4lDywoctxmIl2IHZvBHsZywBYWRFDN0j99oSicFyoZ97xtCvPzi/EfxifPSJx172A3uVBXbDJ/9FJyUC@g4iHAh8XXAASm4xb6LU0dW@G7ZyVBnDlxZxXFLAtFa2QtOvQNjMZf38E27bFKlgjoC5NswCqwX0c3VFdwt4CM2uIVohcUlRAhTfyIGDZozT1fEETNQOPRlAdwNr2wkZORk9sSX1RYcfXGvI13thPoeHbanwxkRkZy0pG04zj/dhK1fd1/iPPd5ufS0bJHsgz4OLhWePktcEIhI5sUKQrdXy88cxzobbsnZcB4APXWAhf4t8WbwIej3A6dKKwYXjHC/cjD6ELQLjnMcxIfAgAtWxskkPBUHN6OWGHdI6fKJGeFHF3lyHEYchk@sz3Jc3OKzMs/BoVVy2kxD/SHE5dexN29ngNNhPrCAI63QA5V6wZiI8sRVaZT47FnjwrpLD4YoogYiAayziZgM/cE4bNHIsCXL6RIoOQZJGuu3pzCh9lpdH@5zhXkIUEMWBQwC5ijpIRwcfWj@u3BQumPmjN03I1Mk6TfguULTPRiFJH0TAvOocDULdxrg01f1E3VytH/6rnpcU/T9zfHR2/pebU/tvOczbhyUc84V9erogKRLfJoup@ZH9CBTPaGaGX7hVA/fq9qPb45rJyfq6FjVX785qBM0An9cPTyt1048VT/cPTjb49N3gqAOj07VQf11/ZSKnR553Kqp5iT11NG@el073n1FP6s79YP66Xtucb9@eojGcKpfVW@qx6f13bOD6rF6c3b85uikptAxZ69@sntQrb@u7RWofWpT1d7WDk/VyavqwcFUR4/eHdaOFTsJWL3cqRGW1R3awqIl7ude/bi2e4oOJd92iXiE4IGnTt7Uduv4UvuxRt2pHr/3NNCT2j@dUSF6qfaqr6svqXNO7itUoXHZPTuuIboIlDg52zk5rZ@endbUy6OjPab1Se34bX23drKpnIOjEybY2UnNozZOq9w0wSBq0Xv6vnN2Ume61Q9Pac04ewN/B5cG@V0Nd5PvVqnqHhMYbhDoLRHp6Pg9oIIOPACeeveqRs@PQVOmVhVUgEfF7qldjBokIp7a3VSHtZcH9Ze1w90aXh8BzLv6Sc2lAaufoEAdDhnviXWo0TPuNcaJ8JKvxKyO4VyPh1PV91V1720dmOvSxAEndc0tTLbdV5rmBSRNsYwo4QA2A79nG1Y6s48@BAj0n7XIzLfRxDFFu0d7NVqRdSxYJnlxRqvO@lSwkf2OVpr4Jf1MBXW0g8ubqyYuhocXVlxNDB@96MpDlmcX@WXPnQfiD7V9hStks83m22qTNronzabrfUvNFBpfq6HN4A@VcnUfkfEPO28YfjY2hO5bKUJtf6cPOj0lyWW4pFD/O15c4VHkqmKxHehqcG8FYGM6iuTY5BpHKSQa2bMeGXGTJtkywb9DzQ5cMWfAF1pN2Emp51JoENGf/ufkhywO1gOSzmLuKhaxiWU0wo@BaUYaYadh/qN9dsMON1mIguDXq1zJbg57/sLVYNBG1gtdh8uOaR94lXO/Uv0yuJqqnp@uz8jysbNOQheZfTerMPH5syaZ0uNSGHHPcvjTHPOHa7ARr2hYTbkpNlZro2XuO6kOjyRPaefvL47OIASd73X1x/o77OZKK882p56/ip/L3EIiCOQMoQWvwfUu@OPVhRSgCcbe6kSSUPuQF4tWHeNvEhe@pYLXKHQbtuH5Q2v1dcDrOpGEFNkbv2u3idV4FN7Z2JMcfnlcfb1ztr9PohPYPltffb626cSBaT968vke7XDWDo7LG9I6Tnoav7JmyS4pPjxTrBRLCfszAxeLKIhcXWbQ@CE8oWO/jbQnEwQZuhshPXQfLnqZAHTIKHZRf@QYfp07MzUD5FJdddGbnn/HKr5PuhLzgHZm6U541O7wB7Dj6W@meNwhzUCaxTiPCXEu7S5Y7mVQib1ZeHPDoS0oUsgYPpZAx5gGbOoqb@jQMP6ledsaxUhcGTFfedi5JiHxaBoLZfwq@jKz37AnvjYAc3wdPflR8xt9fa9DQDkg1I/G1fEJkXE/rgk7dWKM1p1uaMgXyJ2IsEPT0paCld/VSPHc0@bk2HXemg2MCjKPwuM4DXgz9rSfbhKbzqUXS676JJwK93bA2dQcq38T587rjoayaTzs9W/jt60EVhwGIFS7jdtwTJH3sae3IWeKTH@KHgz/H0iTOfC3aMdJ0BNqWWGy30RJhiq0ou0rEyW8NQcN1ulGQk370fsEzBd7YK7jjunTmzsODwUJ9OhMzIP3HBjcyc0hAJgchg17/sYuadc@bZ1eZFxdHeck/VZvmFN6rTBLxQzc/NqFx2qXZ85W8MNVrtiarAYPqKp6IRu3S571tGWa2sqrx1FGwLnGQ774hA0g8YRnLr0Wr9VpzirpWWbkgA5GshacdhxTRGrpl3tP7Z4oK4g8Jfv1yZchFIHeBj6z/eQkkgMl7rnpmGS5yPiU40SRkQnbZCw@Oqjzkh0xuwHgPG6zMQR5Jse3WCC6Ap2DWRNoKveYHUXQSOJ1mETiQty6BSItL6u3MfZsmQSHxtif9SVvWCBWLVOiIHHDGsM@/AyJZ4bDoF9Qr/0Jodz9tm4LixWfnAw8@C6iMTFL6PrIqdkaDEakOvroN@HohRO3oN5po0PQj25GOsKX1rNwpC0SRumnZqA2ye6dlxnJx8WoRSHpDfBlYf7gLvUCeIgyuPAuv6ZyxLyGR7eN0TG8Wy6r3FbyZotowoH7TMQttYZLV7iUEFQH1QdMwTCKNxfss8nt4Nwhnn63g9GvWPuhAvXbQTuO3bdAsi1QBqne5yjo1li6PhxEbNGgoYAFJKZEWQxpsaMqrdHPNTtpv6ZMEj@O6H7uye9vJ2ZS4y1FDSWMq1sn5lvL02CCSis6eD4Opy@vrDIq8zZcX@7djHE8ffrYWmXO@7FI2RAlovLYqI74JnIz/vYe37SRv/I4wuyhJzjj1iooEIbOinPVWTnH@MGn4F0YjNq2TZQ0mbY/hPmNtz6DPvOiMR3qwNiWP46CCe0AWsXwrsgwmrm/DK77zd1B178KB6FP@zSkzLoTiYevE/6KAbsaDW4jThcrdypYhdqT5DufWOtARfyOzyU3reC1aBwMc7abwng0qSKhOHYxHJqJQ9R4vWL@Hk5HEcZ1nq0mlRIHFeBRYH@8srt5b92n5XmV5UQfALSA257yoODQxwB5LCqmpcEwN@XZhwKXDxWwcLxUeeW793jspTD@nkjExzApjA0yM24JdiewM7sX40b7zmtzlO5oMCa5tRcgF2mU48eejwu9SIr8AE@BDVVeL1lV5RTlDpG6@DK5n9wrz//B2BMCfwL98tN53DKPEVjEdfRsIJnMmwkdh0@4sHtgyDKaJTFJsfCKVqFuCmjzbhpq@vXkPmqw5w8pRToQdYYrMSNztPFBVvNck0ROc@JiUVlSSy4Hf0IFqY5zpfsZNvia/yxPfhziiuUMgmlXQ85ZSN9HqhZRCVcETbnX2ihL1pGvz5iVlW8dtSkCVua5nFl3Z@UyRnPhCJRQ1lccaw1GJIwzU9TTrh5L0XgwXPpG6t0rO@bGLs6jdct1v@oILMxWocXySZtJW5ng62TTmcZnimnSFGNPM@IhbF/5e8zm00S8qzQx3yrNyVfocB/NEr@peFGJx7stcx@L4gd49JqFJp5SjDvC@Dfj540mdbx5vwTRMGV71WSJ0YTIaE7kqwVqikwxlb6dQsx9GvcperSJcmi3TbSzx@deok47yZmkAOZVKgwc9ERqIwRtklwaduB8kXPN@VQspGKF886b8FFeOX@JNBx4IQChFQf5xA4lFtxksKb4iPNndXJNeAuVIYno27bt4RCnxYoJxnmrtHFHezw0J/nyxaZAuosh0a6CSz0EST9CsUbzjqHMkIKm@BxSxD2akU3X396rP9sXKkcQpDa/1p6@JQ@dcdUyYUN/7FfNO@jASVO6ZmpGpSdCk0UDzQXapVx1A9muQvsLR8Lx8G7Q04g2EPI4h49lXQMJb9ZKMbVR5a49QRFXk1tmm4vbarhKwlDyG@TXU1FUXd64EoBAMKb6lTJBQOA/Y49DgW7QGac4L4WoHiOqWCljWtJDzhuQ@HnOeQ@i6gLPVq0SpXklvrdh5OcCIcVifpkEEdJZ5hdJoNBCNxcXq8Tz@f1JSpBCbHhfKE5DoUclTcN45ISAfJNRyU0kSqOsvJLmYH75bNVNvYz5m99@X7LelqbfEn1iDBv58vTb9VLqbarZlZV01VRNoodrt5p6SaRwbYRjqfDn/nFoip0UKPYJtTYZKS1D@2fjpinaZdK@rfBLpLY4KNvoGAaeHRlutl9NSUKYSlv0cIoitcRHBshu9Kd7azxTDSY6m9bSeZ@TJ4lxVzaErLFmsNSjW9jpsjcFDCcmQYHZ0w466u3p/r69CUb0sHY06gWj1VKpBCa@tNNDGd9qmJLCQTFduti56XaLw9u/jN5eFln24w7NbjTYMDvogIaEJkVUGIyuJHcacKCiKJ3XgazY6990OnaSMpxQYvBo2KSkzoageAEKY6eXt6eSNHk/WWB/RgfRv59VPPtufVE0NRRzDEW14RL8IWNOz4g8eNCBf3Z8UsXAIJiNNxOtW25l@xNWEOT@48HiBB/up8Q9OfMq6HYHnnqHC2eQKWDhy3SF/X27QkmK4ISRo3tvkB47Ip0s@BB2rbhiFLF5HeDMwmQysZnMScgedRxc1e6GuUzjpwwtK9TlZXRzGRlcPJW5yrg6ndI3gBU@JLS/qXTPH@ZaTKfpwrTU6xmcfCOMnpa9uXufVBGXbWKaZl8vDaLOR7fAyRqo6y7rAibbEw8v9@Se4jFxM@d35Q5oWBIYGidi4O631UCo2T9OLH4YdzrfJhU5UZYM7O@SiJIr8M8JRD4D4Bmopx/RExkz/5qnab0/lVBEFByks5uVO6jQRAXHedyq/Habq1aranG4vKyq1R36gssbdqpqDw92dtQeMuPj93eVldXVTZG5e@4nerhjHn5ROwSDLZzLrevRHv2kdxXEjcFbG0O8WKwsepuLzcrW9mZUbFR3ENZP3/79X/77v//r/yhW9Y//hR87/KPxU1yoUCgUF1ufFr/7sonfjb2LpcXLxuLwYulqE1xGZKjejAf1cd5P3EcLo0snK6uA9ZT9SM0@m7PP6KrKpLzu@aNfSbpsqGwrKmb100hyq7KMzbYC63mAOMpL2sKbtFzTW3kHaY97/gTmeBqdVgAHPFpviJKEC/xApb6crRjDPdLBxAXiU5WszsTDOuuHADEtSSYFxOLSipUP@1HQhwX8A@u80j3H8ekzHDc1/xZ/0jdBPznPqScl9cRTTzIZ/sCt0E/O3cViiOhcKRbfF50cLcDNUEUhK3q8f@BslFPkdpxFTmoJSCZNBReWKDgv3v1xsIykJI6unAXcTqDERMKHTKiS/bTY/0LD8olKfMmkQm1YUWjqXQw3Zp2oxOMLFciPxBEgabknBNkYUJM46eOIZHwrmid6rB3Ot8mAQdbjl/s87/GA1qLFvvZ5Tu2lkAiU3eflKdbGTQmGZrTxRtpPEOADFdlOljiScCm75IiXt9VL7qZEYdv908wnvg6TYGx806XS35TFBOLNbRNusa/jWrQjtxyvqEwYH69YTWWmfb@VY1Xp3XTH4VCHK3DrmFCf4ta@yEzCiDIggSNZcTdmZxgbCkymqKlhkXSyE9UeoOsyE/RtepgObkFOjiwiFH/K0dz@PDW33SJHiRh2EB5gpGJXvo4fdiOddUWu5bvyR5fIn823b6pwLOdmbM/DXQlTGA86MdIFhswu58l8pq5khyP/qud7Kns4OB35kzotW6T5jFsFl3qIFExAApNPNz2vewZh6ZEeEqZI3BX2HEJG3u5EJxCWsc3EMScYUjMVdNoVTIIUOzElg8@psZqiY8LVv2MQbJRnhHd8GqlFLEteeBppSBk7bIan2czUcUwL9tyJJ07GEVTjmWl4QVe6wULb44NfkuRd5AjQbWd0FKAORVj7Hu1jdboK@n5qcRp2HRPoX9xUsi5iPnOydvFGcjSU5@UkJzSwIj3yp3QWCFmbTDojZyGXWziPdMLjrL2OQHkuxL74RV@FcYpmTvHLkSHqrB@KsJxaoUKhPTFhQdXZ858gdLr@FeE3ufUnYMXzbO6HR0W38dN5/@JJ7rz/@fyjy5hokWxW2bzK6sNsI7H0XKGVseilfhqvtIhIwAmczvvpAud9JTEsFgkIkWKu8VPx4nOREDrPuu6T4nlWCJIaMmBSfLi9IsAXZ9DMprEoZp0F94lrBj/3Q9lVtLbyJ8ZQHrjySViYTSWb6WmfM@oQKI7T5RuisbErrq@Unq2Un9FO6Cq4y4@CG6y3@ejmMrgjVSLCdpaWnvOPKW5IEeLLXeRv0sM76md41cdNnzyikQ5S0iJUT3Nux4nZiuoUhCeoPFE5BxIgxMWNy/g4fMSG31PEcqYs54IS10GL@3JYP6NBD@34EeTadHSIcCS8DMRHhE2oeUDWjHcvh7pmuixxnFNB7V4HNMgAQsNbzFqrRX/Qz2tlzS0sbUKJRtRMF/c1Ts/RmSmamqGLWplaeqTK2z88/7f/efRbdpzdXim@G9HnOPtbdm09K1/pC/16an59yG5nt1Bs7Ut2UqQ9MH19/m//m@pv/4Xg4M1ki/5srxpYa5Psdr7CVT5nt9foS3llhdr9P//8z9SHRdmx4baCxaanGLFNQ5Fdv8@8S@9VHb2UbelSIlY4MAswxMOQ9ub0A45RdyvrJTbTZbVXxYdAZ74y/ih6iWfHrDG7Coklw/hTkGYkFSpoIC8gjQtFR1m@G8ZtA8yboKl@flxYi2gH8LN254ibjF03HkdwGVqUbRENYE5apP28fNku/ZCJ3Ts2MsanZNOokNjaaVm7/nST2OHNIBiHrbSXhJmuvZZ/G1wWwIeFoH1De6p@1B38Mip@IJbslVfWix0Y94vsx10cMqT8cFL4SIqgzjBPG0N2OvXUiEZg0EMKL4/zzpNCvx@fSZmM66RlD4OW2LDSt3ZQEYnx8@R4GN0pJKp0jv@SAo/c8jpVupVN@LxPNY@ON1RmOS4o5XjP6wKbN@wcq1Ng5MUblm8lJAWG@wDroOlPoTq64iAkrjUiCFKk4LfbTV@/yzkLGZNM2HMWroPusJJh3zDqzeiGXYs1/UXNvBdKPoQFIZ9nQQdYvWDs0xa9kuEn2I8nLSBNij5rjVPFJWTt6LJ6V9@u7HOw6v1N30rTtzSi0BKSdmKesbKxKbuYyJYKTJWjoIkjtbkNU2uRudZkVOAPYBDJsNQ7CEvQ3eEISKJa0h3tVWYPm8d7YeKR20Bi9sS0KHe7ONkk@NEzJSSCGroT2i1IYyQgDgf9YAMeyvT7RCIgKiYRf9h3JJ/f1GuT30OD4T4cDYN@Km2dJB@VZalP6yErHIilVEQCnVfW9sF2ZPWIQccptuJLGjIwvGRcsFRngzdbXNAMxwZflGJSQmUyYqdqtFR8AUNH3@/AKRTwIFMqrzx9trr2fP175AFe0L2dDwaVCtgFDK99gsEadY422XheqWSWMvIIl7TMNgno88DiAA5uXbcuYyVfH1XKJQ2slGFYt3zZiFTX5koGmUAcBQWsCLRHyY0yudwPGw107OK87X6m/4m/TX5AZjiTjtYX0lvj8CbJTOX0JOFAhQUzJ8XJ4a5kWkLkjV02GHSOkW0igK@rsD01dIAMEOPr0eDm6trmjoJObXVKE4YIPh5NNngH9TIYJwnGLKygi2qDQ92KvqgYeI3ZHsApF0sCdD4BTtNM5630tacpZscSLULIrImIVRwhWq6jNjszd/YHqna4N42Yvt2G87cK3ILt2UrKHWcyQwIZ3GZhdfeUqKuzXXAoqZZJXiqrMgu4EsqVORzeR6x0C1e1WFQxspr1hnHuIbKUmReT1KZJVRpH4DUHZrn0dVKauFbTCxDECEJtTYqFmBef59gkS3CyBxnzFLyc2bB8RF@HUcQJ5nRjGVd7lHIhGshITiXmAYTdppSRjpQ2MKL8tcZXk8hoI925REXDNKDdkOOdajC3ZNjRpgKOGpds8TEt0P/64a6n9mr0Z//dngdFeaf6V/Q7vgTlfnzLGt/yhqrvmyGws8Wyzy18pn5DiBIxS0knjE0QhPBlwwbqxVkDavV9TXuZ1I3U3L5IuALs6msl3FhH9SRBohe2gSzozXucioPDdfjZhhivZiVNnFJFTwsxcT08sS2aLCStxpCElN8AYmUaRJyoJeH2hYThxQOdNW9f710MY9f35/N0imVlQ0Vq@36RyJ7m2Xsp8xBbrGi2WNnAOD7EF8y3D/LGZdAZ6Fi0mDm@whuP/hhv5L@dOfL/XzBH7R/DHU81dzzdgOwR7ojThnNEJ19UNJjDMZcTXoOb7fAqhH2oY/1EJ0qeBYAFHjBEDCm9LJfQt3vEicrNf7E8vR7BSWhldc35g51/pjv/bAMyl7/uBf@vdj7/d@78qu786gbWmjkjr1U7K93636fHiUqYSz@YO7xQd6WY@0d7uqZ7uraB1XTOMP@X9zT/n9TT57qnzzeQMUEOHCR9/cPcLJpI9WS3Xk/cLQrmVskcbnqaz5Uu9l7tSoY2D53uTXRdgbau/jD@6xr/dUgj/nYMsvpWjHK8l5ftqQTLi2bJVg6FICvpifTXZEa3@qsXrGQ/ohcoEdJs2BrpjQop5J68TE6bCon@mEjfePH5VpxFtnP@Q0m4am2gZUdYdpMpLpovFzaX6i0IIyMHsto9PT5Y/m9Chp7/q45CI@QxtLdBt2tWEnsLdhpnndKdsboD2Cd6z5FiFU1ORnaso71jdlm4X6pxYoupdXH@JkGO2uQKTGSJtG8WYJMR0aag65tdFVxzzfZCnlDfpdD8Luse/yEu/V5z6fcb6lhvDO4jla8NfpoXk33ayurqQ2uA1CrgAxOw5FH5B2bVfySHC7PuH9UOqNN8HURRtm5fQWPdvSplFMqodJnqDZUZbahdP@hfwv/gbZx8asWxbtCkzUrkOLuv905gu/AvW@2gc3Ud/vJrrz8Y/jaKxjcfbu8mH8sZxzEXLudcuYnKeN9oM8XsHZyZUWbqIs68dRNnAgKG@SWxmqQNIUvl8pLb2NhYuXAV5mdP8jHJ@UACgFXUftT1afDYzSJOdc5DKR4M07G9ER/9R2PEnBPJcl2/d9n21d2Ggv91vuwpeIPppy0iJJGI7TC5FknPoeu6cseRiNolG/LGkmf/tLs6uurVxT6nMhmNEv2s84EAjC1x0dhC02CTy4V6Qswnb8J22lIiNpm4pk5/yxeDCJ@uPLtwN4hM7/gNGP7a747lRDD30Y09YYJxHEmApXNXhBxWkZKbClywkN7iBTDumKuZIznlkv5acjX13monhtFIwF@kCqdoZf1Ypqkfh@4QMJoKg53BoHuA8TUteJoanlpPOpNkK0ZY8yu/24lHwdxAGYpTZYp30n3kewFB7dTATBFCE6MTS7okmPoazQ60pTiuj8OGntwZFo5nQNn4otJMgRkuYRmayunDi8Z0PRneaCxXxM7pRMKcjRgJvvcz4TfreVb9eHTMl9KMQhi2xNpWpjYKQYHm5xU7/I/d9IVhqURFenKtrNK8iiHzDHNnkJvfp/tQzs0@pH2vfogGWO6gA@PbQdwFrGZXnN3w60h/A8oPTOcUhwpYsPc@LUcxexumLq9ppW5pCUhr/XHetEtzN1h7BB/j3PrUYBs6YHqtgVzmwYXoK8nrdYwzco7RGjDyxZ0sq87GIQnxSeLTzMoNO4zZWhYnIRJgct/y9ARuXXvqUv/Q@XU0ppbwAG347uVrN7k89p7OGWANccdYVs9x5s4MEUMkBY7TSbvzJCIai38W1Yp7f3epFPoZzSqWU11ODer87g5ubARKX@1nUt58ozXEluMzhAgv0iwwC8GIWu06jLVBv5rlbBxJNZvI/dNscqqVZhP6Q7O5JK2IMvF/AQ)

Polyglot already has Navigator 9 with disabled JavaScript at [#266](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188876).

I used [Live DOM Viewer](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer) to debug this answer, very useful tool.

Browsers usually add `<style>` element depending on where it is found. For example, in html `<style>` it will be
added to `<head>`, but in `x<style>` it will be added to `<body>` because `x` switched parser [insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-insertion-mode) to
["in body"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody).

Navigator 9 is different, it always adds `<style>` to `<head>`. So setting `document.body.innerHTML` doesn't remove
`<style>` element as in other browsers. That's why previous answer displays `266` in Navigator 9 regardless
of whether JavaScript is enabled or disabled.

Moreover, `<style>` cannot be removed with `document.head.innerHTML=""` because Navigator 9 doesn't expose `<head>`
through `document.head`. So I wipe it by accessing it directly through id: `t.innerHTML=""` where `<style id=t>`.
Note: Navigator 9 doesn't support `innerText`.

After this manipulation Navigator 9 starts displaying 259, like (latest) Firefox. It is separated from Firefox
with `document.dir`, which is `'ltr'` in Navigator 9, but `''` in Firefox.

`t.innerHTML=""` breaks IE≤8. `window.t` is undefined in Navigator 9 despite bare `t` being visible, so `window.t ? t.innerHTML="" : 0`
cannot be used. I use `n-416?0:t.innerHTML=""` to fix IE. Note: `t.innerHTML=""` doesn't break IE if placed at the end of `onload`
function, but I use the condition anyway to get rid of error indicator in the status bar and not to deal with multiple
reference screenshots.

Other changes: `+`  `- -` for DOBELA, `""`  `" Elinor,"` for SPL.

I use profiles to run Navigator 9 with different options. Create profile via GUI: `navigator.exe -p`.
Use profile: `navigator.exe -p nojs polyglot.htm`. This functionality is not mentioned in the Help.

Answer (score 1):

## 419. HTML+CSS ([NetSurf](http://netsurf-browser.org)), 18300 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""^ x._,_  \;ncepp   
 ; ;:在ｕ
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({d937189e-2cf9-4742-8348-f71b154279b7}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4UXHh@RFZYHXzCYAA32SRVdXV1bfrqh@l6up7r0Wy2SAIkrgFAmwArCK7ih33ahxayZI9tix55OeV5fGsvPLEeCdm1nKMvBNhT8R@mXDMJ/@Aku3YDdsh/QPtOZkACFaRVX1le8OxIAHk4@TJzJOZJ8/JTGR2VXf405/G8CKHtjkbmLZHPN31SM8xTnVHJPdmZEc13IKS4ziE2nUGk5FueW6VixGZEFO1BhN1oJO@YXq6kyGurpOubtpn4K8QsjWxJq7ea4AtR4iln5EDSzN6gIF49oluGa91B/zyhNzXzYvRhUc0ezRSrZ5Lxo5hedS3QMihCpb@RDshatf1HFXzDNsCr@JSFKUlW5mQx7bj6oDJ1nTXtRFXZQlEzpJ3VYhvbOrTK5hlmXxg6E6P0FSMHZ2lRVbI@8cPHlx1zZHPC7ZFHmAKr3jlye7Esw@8q/gLZHegWypRxIqoXPUsAp083Sxny9mrXiUoKt0ztKvxlMluv29YOnkMeb3qWSGa6wqu5hhjj4OiJA8MB4pZ9YuTaKoFxYaFmiL6aOzNiMAqgmqaYSG7RHXJxJ2oJoWzJqOu7gSArqc6nmENyJnhDYk3NNwwHIV2x6qmCz3dNEaGp/eIaUAgu@9jAdRWj5zoszPbgbL3cdqWOYOAumb0DQwSpAMQ4pXwhjrDM1JnUHEsD2oJUYkLyTD1AFuSiwH8fb07GRB74o0nHoG09QxX7ZqAtDsjPb2vTkwvQ7rgB0VC3c@GuuXXakAnAopjm6XqowlNmr6o/GqvR7JQoSEdJzoxgGo0WVWSy4E7sR2gGkAFKfKR0QrO8qhPoYShzPp2lRSyWfDfD10wtarp2n5ilpOGnhY0WlpmiPfQsQeOOgJq9HRK0/cPDomr2Q7Y4EZY1rBuQqOpHtnaIvH9J/fjpBEWi@h0ubCI6uQciiAWeJJT1ZxADYmWhA3l44ShOSyy@Ea8SuJAFiVL8nmSh/ZbJkoBiCRnK2AARqDkZLiLRCmTvAztrUByAJxToHEXwQcaBMlnC/EMRt531IFh6gz1AFGXsO1AGAWe2TzJQbPIFXMMemCbfQaq0VSUSK5MiiVSKpASPCukokAyMM48tJgC3EW4AWMF0giIlBykOKswZItGAZUYK@Ie6asjw5z5MdAoNFKQSQmwQmZkwK6UAQu8czm8c3CXEdvyFcXtDaEohuopoBdM4wR5mR6yMyxfCV5SKiVRvomMmUXvDjF6oCtQtFAmJYi@CBTJQxKA7EoZoi9kWUbcoW6afrChi8FoaktZuCHlJaBFGYomCzTNIlFLcIMdWKcCPFIBhqgAj1OALykKmHMYBcBhWRWhnIt5Fs1QdU8gIhaP0qMFAHwf0MhIceSHMhIJMECpESA11IE81JIc1pJCjkD6IS2lIoEaUJZJOU/KJQL0rGQJlI8M6cIqJAMrliE9MiKDeiBDRZAhTTJQWwakcq5AuAix5Rz6Q9gchAXSyHkIkwczFJxcxBvCQe2QIUoZ4lSUyqKGQtqUAuS3kKNVVylC6ZbAD@imQFoVqFJYX5Uy@GPYMtCwjDW7FM8wQqhIBygVbAtQF4EYBUgPxQuwYFZKfuVVzfFQ7SLjZyG7fQxaxDZSRDJC0CxmD955pCYkJQtosDVA8hWoATnalOCdD6M3ZUDSRPR6z6Dc28QeRA4pVMrQCvmROvYWZJOLNEXjmTcM3RTmZgNXNYAz6gNVm4We0AozoefCtZhDV4Uy4gWibB5dXWC79sQ1F0hCQ16hUemnhrlwK1O3nq72@oY7fLNIa55G0tVVzzJOFrEUCpkIUdWIRxE9lpxKuSisZwjQlw2GaFrkRSkhzNgOC2gpybJMk9fV@xNroAuVciR91MebOB70Oos4K8zZMQYD6MEXeOQMzSbtRRfOBZpCM5eDzj1wROpinI4Bfftdog1BNgk9Kwx/pbLAkVMQx0ztYpcvgKwGXUQFO7W@MSXduxrtUhYJzFE6aUNjHABX1wJHCpdGMi0XI3WDUu51ORuyZ7za4ke2YSXiJJ7k5hx0REz@jHbj0Nt9gF0YdspYdaHTtalIsWCfCSvoNpNAtGUJALpkEyWlrq6p2D1jZ6XTzjbAY3gigUhAiNTtUxRuaY@5FI1Le9Wug7IsiEA93XEIwoIA7GZo/@tOuq7@aoJC1iJdfejQdej3@6phhgmg/YjqUekA3nEX4pstJ7vv2CPa2YywfzVte7xGloHe/AwRPbTP9EXSF529Oh6bIFKBu84kOkjMmUqlcirCR2NlCYJAGA4KHBDSqEAUMRxdo7T3sw6hcyC0LCexSpTG3RxiuReRtXLQWEAOcTGMNTHNKghBukZyDamnn0rowuSxZTkM0xBIaCBn@Si6KojdmHKaihDTXUWkst9xULKuPVrOGutfD8KsDw2UmswzdQal14euVZ@qI1AOCErg0HLJCGoMK0EsCdAiMFsHpGdbcS/EcuaAhAuZDnNCpWikiWeMdNCRbAiCJZ6nicbenaasO4OqTKmVF6lSxFJyhVAid5VQzCEfcWCNBWTB3kRDqmHchkVrEIhLLioADrBK5sZ5Dmm1VLgdEPbGvh4oogEBn2HSIuqEy1q7L5ZrFCMKsLrlgobiisRALQ1q/sDuQ2U7MyDvwLAg6AK3RomAJAidpqImcpTkWIFGJyYxiDYeE3CHTgmq54NsGeRT@yODvAZPcwj6hTZxnBmZjqEkjBFAeZrd70Ptfa2Ph4CCjHpEm2nQPKGQae1xh5Y65no2ZTPaeDmzC9umDjAW6i17hz9PBjoQH2TaPmqNWPEX2RiPaUYoQVSLybuWCvTCjGjjGSUOF1uE6Nu2iO49W3dplbGdk5ABYGSuPqANBFpbf8GSRii/Q121qN7RA/7jNzLEjxFyKzODUfl14V3dggakQd2Epg@FiCW7S/qgkEcEWVRFVE3Tx55fW2zK1AwrohI8fYAqAXUVfGSiO@Q2d8jWlboDoGH9iUi0qCJh0se@pqIix/W1foGKH6FWyviLObsWPUCcXomdf4kwSyl4ya9Jw5g2DNSPKKuYeMhQkEca2hA5ooc8h0rd0OacyfXsg1s0emdEhH4YN6ZGBubDiVLohOlYj0OA27yOSBybiKux5ICgSw63oFbd0QrMdphIsxd1FSVVBNZ4G9KRbdkrsAIxQ7wIsuxDy4JWxmfIO1QzrIy0ubhLZYRsezEQhd0Z9KTjse1Ay2CsZ0YHG2iRRWqXr6Mnwh4jKZJ7yx0sdBxx7PY97AshwNhUoS5gE8OWCvqVCvwCWBnToYHz2SzGSIJpq6e4/PSd0Q6AVSboUS1LRxVNdWYMCWQPOmmIaEYMxwFmeIpdBeuJgi5FpPUUega110P@iuSg7f5q5CLW6L1J15heVdQ1dBQ/crlT1SF91NEdED2gESXifTeerFF3GjLixUv22JNoUPbkAZACiVDkiT6o/dBVPABG82xmaQl@qYnxGcJPvH6ZT4IBAzJJjbwHCsPV1KESgZVmdALtmtpqZACduCDAU0A3mhL0kET0UB2QNqARgq5ZqfS6KrkA7uEQYbrHFJJAMZHFfBiXbvXCuHxCYFqi@RVZFK6jUYMQ6dswBwhOc047iSUCviUlaEAeHCTJ72HRgcp8zI9KN8xxYtGBPZJgAkmSnIciMHQACZoYA0QQQzO8ji@03L0biC8b9TpUNpCpgG32klG9Nhj0FIFTA7BIZRI/EtGzn3nYNhJJyC8Cz1lqQHiCmlpvkHNv6ECLo/Y5B0BAVs7CmhwQ1i/nJ8bJpHe1oC10RCAeWx2ITobm8TUORADWGuo3UTW@RFXQfeNIVay8GJ6ivlZ5qSsWKO@DObqLQnDdT0qkhBOYAr@uriQRC@q7LSr03kwzfZGAmaCxM27UheSf@GNdISPK@DJB0GivtVSGBJsDw0MOd48f1v22yDylrmFVlxxMW1NN6ryJ4HwQ9tHBvaPdo5/vrMBhGt3qVQfJyJeL2NVOpsLAmkh5UaluRnEsEN/v3IwbAy7D8JzvTQR7GhGVZhp0LtOAnE@PPn@VJCAJITloDGDG@4pIw2BA6OK6qju80gmTQToNUYZBAlgiHJAAZ2jApKO/GqTncPL6NRbe1USNfXdMmTlRGYLAUTqwgnAiel4RwAKvbp/1iDQsyKKGhRMZC1MUMkjPuyg7X00MFagjVebdpw/2j@oUrT@6JlAQyfVAllKdngh13pyAIr4KBtgfmDSSFhcJR6mapnUlgTVticCLsiVr8AMC1HhEmwjmKMiaO4S0713NG3UVtLAGUDvFcFWujMpD2mdNaCQd2MVpqPiu6kWpx6KzCp1W9lih73K3pRUKeilfiXZb2iLOXhQpnTeAfiCQGx3wOnEFdBEXUqQvVvvJf/boWsJdKkSCKiAEKXNNItK4XJND7UUwSNyV9kBPs01d/IByPJ7wSUmKB1MHouZSFTQCvz81vEQ2yd5yEmAh9t3dA@V@AOwPXNPxDKo0oEaOPZPTx7lAzYU6YtmmPbBJCsIw6TCIEMSmtdncHdjWtRJS0RGzGsPpROC/OHyjjqGvMV5T9ZGGiiqtbGJStdwz4NJyMYdEohSiqCQKL36knqpArkW@nx18cR86EbmQzYbmLL2ABJEwlFxo0iKu1IEIEJHop2dlBsP5x2utPfAQIhOAmGmf0YUBdxfeKx0pxxSllfArk/SefY3iH9mzK1ULXFjVAkOEZAdPDh8dPNl/vPthy1MKhSV7PlspAuEgvi7IQuKQ0Q1ba4o1TcwWootB23CweQEXmICCEkwoTVwHGLeIICJLwJpaw2ZuE@/ZQyvuJq9m5gx9hY8sjVWhx9j4GKgfEBTtnonKiMNmtrE/x/oz9LyxW5UkaOXDSVcEpVX6SLNNdSDRcNAxmKYko@py8BRHN9xVISAx7kxnIdgQF4gOMzqOqJojG5QXOj@OrIEkGHo6dmUagyHowjiJrjtJMazBNDdSDzQE0JWlMG@UAVMb0NZ/B@XEs6r9jqyUWb2Ws0pe4gOwpeYPsBt9HVSnBPRWQIrkFStp3W3dJTPg0ojpKpIYEVN0kMMl2BeYBARJOnaKen5AHMotcNQUeQWl0asJjukCl5IK2XxJLhYkUMtATQOZVcCRN2GketpQ8GwB8Al2n44bRGph39VUqy@mfEOQWJD77kBWc80XrZbVBgG9dZemDaemm7N2U24na@R6kJQPn6xB7V3KHtbdwAHqLjVC1aRvsoaf9dTr7Kyn0tbVI5I3Gvt9jjAmj3dBkHptA7/u6dG2hwGkqKeUWoKVEPiNtGJAyMSgHD6QUhI0KOhpoepJmC4BhF4UD6HmAN@KBCCL0YxQYJp5Q@AfOZLYo6bkdQkXnXM@11hOCg4Ni@MZsDwKhExbyGGCAg8a4ZhhwKTEQQVCiQf94ywJdCDh2AGWPoZiYgNae9ARgDrn4lCkh10wztlM2NgwNknfigOeu8IXiSq8vkm4CKAB8eX3f9D38YRim0juqVjjgApXJDs/oEieIwuAvnxGPDrS0NNRjcf1Ec8tAxURkaO@AnRd8c2O6DkbhIe4Lr//J5ef/Pbl1z@5/ORbl5/86uWnf3T56X/YEN6gjtnYSrdagphptgkfv5b4O/vKnd17d@6VaQpBnoTE/9@/8Kt/@2u/tJz2FfH@6OOv/ejjX/ybX/rkr3/w8Y8@/tKPf/j1H//wKz/@4VffKl7r//plW/vvn9h@lGc4NBKN0I8PohsOoRd9CFJbM3Xn7JxsbGxA8I2NbSiJje1tkibb8BTguQH95jb4ZuC5TZrgu0HaZN7mQIN1yYrRPpGOn4u6qg07wC01PZFLitDlnV9ML8hw2JyK0M5PeC3Ft@d0don2BTjjwhK9h4X2jC6RwbS/B903sy0Svy7qptRqZlvt1nmi1UsnW3MpI7dBy@4Y@HATSrIpi6IAbshbEpJ4Xp5LYdqmFBKARG3oLFJGJ@zYih3UpVmFf2BMoScCVgkVKTomT1kLndzBodUv6uPhzIkChONVIJ/i2PNiIQiul0H@F@Uvr1n4qCi0pCMHEiODA7EQh71Q0hjPGF/kWEpb0tI6pKDHOhX6I9tTpfdFUDfESEcT34hLggB9CPVhmGi2HxuuBqqFaun2xI2O0a0cOsTYwfV4OAH2vTc0xpyuDW2o6TuAk4SzJEhknPAR2LRREKyniXBjs0aWgVMM0BvTNToGFD5tvXQUQ6ZRn6qm0QvHsgvF8SsxjK1Gw5AsRmQMLNvRBSAEhODogiS63o1rBLO5B3Sk6Bqv9H1pF4B819C9DHlg2iqlqG1BXYjURpwLWYQHfRaCHOk9zrSI0AfRQmQl4Og9KcXRuU3bGQK7hNzglI0SltHI95Bsd9wTvSkE5RLYQUU9mTYEQtoZ6SmKUtQK/Wrgh3UBiD2EokEtzgKVMPASZPBM@kW7z4ZRAp32ydP7@2ysgXZO2B3huFNnZPcmIIf5esaRbg0yZB9qkWHZI2ClVhD@9Yl5ZNse04rBsm4kgymZxmhiqnSM5Oowxo3hNLtrm3To5KagC/iJ46qmygZtAt/d9x@DbPz8@FldrEaAJPV0dGPcOG63OlpGz4PoTB2dpQymU1xWMfnNAo/dXLCiEpmL71FGjxGumQRZ0deiqTV09AHP5ewcYdeqGyGcTOGYjLSI6FxWqPup1@8vOeeo84mAvMRcOOepM1tHuaQOOd0FUIEB4aLKJZgooiKFCddWroUrUTi2nAMq68KjTD1UutJSwKH7Jd8K9V0stUTpx@dg4YT9UDeDCbgjfWTjJBP0kibOZoBoj4IsWwypQ18xxrkEyqZxhgq6BBUCXhW0oImNBQbNxTZos@kaloQTRdymRPwR4hptOKB1s5k9l7FQGzRjOviw1WAzwqh5OEzpkdjY9WYHUGw1asHitHVgGFM8HoJRrDRtEIJmk06CX8tquKTBpUPSHA1S41wJhO6pkhVa09J@@yIuuZQMfcK3WtM7WeVDkElw2eHmXWmg1@h6oDX0qgU@ccqw/b6co1BseFcbAnch6ekyKaF8JlbfNnsCm0uCukaYFoIF5E/oh8sh/VWvuuEEKyHpUlQWFLlqZBHlNbxXirRxHSCy7DJEhOIDuTjJnF6Q5kmGnIru2DQ8EJFQnhj6q4qsqws06XyW6jjqzOX89SB1snv07vvNbJth4EYqzg@VWSlOg3W@oLU59gRXZoMJV7V4hkd7fTprb2B@QciBAHQqAZIPOFgENRJG5OeISj76xSIvfR30uYROxaXZKEP05Fzsm6rn6Rarc2ySbj252WyKH02dRr/tD81XSZbOXxh9SCX4QRJr5Nnx/f2jIxEFukR8H@c5qtAcQXQEYWRdpgNKRjNfJXd6cXIHwyRRueWgqYG63vHDQ6WuQaWf6Dibg2xnoDsJcEziFIUGznRWiAZk0phPIFybpHmURiGyBCjb2wxZdWX6n1snln0WlngVanyaUhLInbhbRSkzKU4s45XoQvdCBU0A8fUp6CXqmwnKyTblpL/4bIQTrCBUUwERctBsEtCZ@E0A5km7XWMz5QALfuCG1OV5WhR0OXhdDoq@Ds4gyFAMfvD6G/KimRUq7fTmKlR0IZa/kpvlP4IXMSyjdvWV0W4maHu/1pBZGtiMGePez126/HH5e4Yq2WQGno3MUvBgcRFlOnQt0vKaouUVS9DIkJXQAQvMSMASYv46e7/OUn/K@UHrxWDUIZEk5yHRFSQ5ubigNCSbCqE0BJNMWGHMA60YGNMjG3LzyF9jH5UJaGv1l1tgm21xfKBoL89nog8T16XTKzKpcMpHwzGZ0LBObDorEpo6WVEuoBwYhh6dmNdD4oJN@lgCDdPAYJV1qXNH3T59rACgkwP@tDN1oMPOvgQMoqMqHdEXHYFeEfPyUoulaP2lnLSnBTMRXt0CKVTKFLjf7RrrQIEIuIYqeK8AAyaF9VkR86IcLNo3LKj1psmGIkBnWWT96iodskR3f82p//4fH/eA/tdLZwgdBY7PhYYOdN1YUkJ/bWH5QdFCH6sLlg0jT0xDpYShpttQaqoDWVLN0LAaNZ2qFgTo/kc48O6XONRNfIDAeUM1Yyln82bBe3Ukq6aeLGCZ2jrYK6uWWFR0kgTUuR4lAhOCDJ0GoqyLFYI@ZRMVEXUa2djtiQqWFhFamVm5DyfehD1B5r21EI0x3je1TR8yW1C7si6xVd43FLmjnkx6tjA@GYRyanEF7CL3dBRJAHHAnzTtoHF19lkG2arp4L0ObNG1SWf0dVutcK2JOxa6VPfuMRttCKMbYnBM9lwHYvifw4WG9VQzTPp4y5roY4eK4q8ZkHBdphAhmnGFzKbanaEMMvzstSycfweOU9fS6WxuzQTseLw@POqbNHylsjr0VNQYPVaNDEhs7aeveNEM@6tBbylV6K6MkWoKSi9iXMvMV03fXwMNZ/5oGPxQgX6tcGMlxw5Jm5iqszDdUMWvDTZfG7b2u4tDQ7NBDBgTuSTKStBlRDoKyiqDhWOLCHDJLX1EFgcYq8gXfHIhhKbVTd/WPFxQuaYuvQUjYwsZcblopHKI9joKafYZ3mvFhiGopOy5uid7vTJVb8GUBFMzVei/13YDS0OBONR4SwU9M1ydPlYT9mRlQj3NXOm@XPWDQb7ooN1t1dk1TNslz@jzJgINHKACe66uyFFaGqol0AHvqPkG3hOsAFgUqGoObLNYHkgqPNaW@sTpI7/332/L2ULOJMu3cKZA7LEt2X@v5ecnknNyWwHRj/ocXP0ZMd7Qta5iT/4Mx/rcgUKAXzesztmDbJmGFCU2ELgmYlzzcqbOgvfP0GWsI23QZYxnVIwGqQ4DVMpg8BwmWv8sseVvjq33dkzpGtrSbZmIFO6JqUMnRZ/XipQoWfkzhpCz2bdnUX1zok/0lQrG0@5HOn7FfoNy8faJyvrZ2PTH5XEqAD/fCKFe@xrhW6Ua@2e03chMVJz6u12EWWZqY5C6x6gyH4LhEA3XQwysyXipVJe0MuvoZpINx0GTtntLqUOfz8qHyrdISEtyuavT@0ZNiWl2uHyqXshms77gEplfWbLcpEHlwrAfGey5FDF1WcS8gMU5NSdiXB0HJUt0gd5aFqSsU@gpcKUiWYalezN8viU37dq2@VlKCpgqflRrg5Yq0IWoN5XYNXHH/8SCLIYsXBzo6PbXDVaw3sbXKYE@qCzfVOjRCaC3Kk0BpzhHOP20bF0dBw5Hmuqo21NJontmJ1eInktR4NefOBDE1qWa6wVJfwhEFsti6cYmx8RTu6ubKntNi/mb8FXE3I34ljmGPy@L87hs9nYx1x67wpHGM6CU0QPVZKiPdGq9QbRXe7jBhP9aCzS18V7nPdV1TZru69o6gLEBTMHC59J0cURS8mwLlCoPl8ChcmLiIkvfdT0RH6uOYT/affLu0tqD6yVfJQcjdaCz7VJu4pqLQQtc6cNUu4Vx9fBFldzD5qpBsEXk62sINLATfeYG75UIH880KObJ6PYhtyuMQMNx0Ldo@esWe17vbq2hPbSG@pCtsA5t69oKVE@PbW9zU9Ih1YMhLvoaj5cWg0fpadoQ6i3oiWySMU3b7q9M0z5@LIrfOH0mvOzLdP916wCe6jFWgoa1jWioT6CPcm3PHusCta0DNXGwhz3X8dNgjvtnHUW6UdcHigTvnxX/rXrmQLW98Zi@OmNz4tIHDSrQb3xvk6H6bFEKXT5oOwPxtT3qir6j6K9YodPgqzlO1/C0IX5kzWq2PrC72tC4LdH@xg5SMOzDrG@lxyJlDCLcR2fRNIC8zkzE@lKP@j/D18G6QvdHkFhHFxpukF1WjdLRz5iFsXqiuWxEFE2kioPCkdbIPnau0s/Fq68mhrdAGlnFFA7xsqkJNKxLu7/4Yq2URb8mWLBhf1HG2lpKBXYUzgU9C8KPvC7a5XVtkSaWy7HHSp6h2dpJPxjWWktJf0EPHfwzIsOy4L5UdZZWIq3UJqzhZOBe54VsNL4Hkhg@1o9O0AW9kRFp6I5Uy3@to6BiSvilH7w7IFpN9BunTAo3zplQONkUVNuAVwdeUCqTtUNlpjF22ZMI/bUzbf4CJVC5r04HMtrMVuvMfsH09D6b4UDTbfLmyHZAMB@AtCFoOFGOA@TIp5lIwXiSZQ@AXwsmWQAHsOv0w5ULiFYXf9gdCh8@0QcqriZ@ZHi47nJFraDtY9XCo1txf2GiusYXJpCzdZUNNy9gs4xOdNkp2lbge6wODO3hUkGEifQJ7C/aZK@l6o9O18vibGi4uGApNNww/oRVjlVirHUdUA9WQF4dlg/3bVg0IPYt4EroVUPn9niGn0zNqOmmUXPDo4Op/nudhrhuediNiTibjMYT13@tTgNdEhUdbB4xduaeGYBceAVckwxV01s9IB0ZWQUBy@/vFsbVUVbJFw3THpAvlrME5DGQr1DuXlFx7kHPe4jrbRxrRU2kcb/lrCaOZwgOy9grKFsdV/ZbhnfzoI3n4dqb4I2ZYZ2CfQbywCN8ijufFYNwvJoij24X4xff597SdUPNe2ZPHE1HY7jpRlTi92PV94IlxQZuU4CbhpxF9THNNqF5gcFc2WQ025p4gjOxbuwVijf2ClXceClSDUjiC/uPnyejtYEuvL5NwAy25lqY1q4HuFLJDAtkrPV8dBk6UBPusy2Djuj631vC7OK@Rhpl1/ftVarM4Qw6kLfWhYD5T0b3dQ1nBW@N@4n92LZs6I3GwChHRzr78H1pHcfqgBjsEX7aDfTp3RrNM4p2TSfEpA11rHehfM2F6W36Iob4vuqpa7oiOgRIVbvQdGtdMcyu7nxEx/Yi5nXa6nKCHupTqjasrzCsDQqepjFpF4fdltrI0sSMO7Ztiz0pt83CS358M1eBroA@3n4eXMTV9Usq/0rVazmrT0/ZIhC9x3ZmWJdXR@/aJnvesOTIMtiUv@oYuis9wg/9qVsxTwSQvtwbeUjpRh6y0HpAkj1VXToHv1qLWKCUp59hhc9QdTQbJ7x8ww2LbyJf59/CpsMF@2xdQBcIPwWOpWoTf9/M25Jljroj@lirMERK80iHaHq4MvDZzPLU6fXCZIM@/vf8kQVb4VfwAbvCRl0kiUPQRpK3d1tRRfAKVY0xfVBOvXZWnK7FESxD116rOCBmU3othqCX/CHP0hNqXDMkHWlGdLBYUunn3itb0vLKNBBoTF3whg6o85J30yh2sNfIimmPyUjHueTlyZa1oqvtDmlm7dXT5iFzdXTB3/YOeEm4BR6TD4XdtZInoof/03vvSdAJd4r5YP8NYF23T9RD4ieO5b/epgYe2q7XN6ZPId24yH8dO8FsFSAIvFjLQFNqXSag9KyJyQYWBpFlVaMeVccEuluxIJiUXXu6oFunAt0NbXo9Rzb7fkvaxY1sPb0n@JsB4ISC8Cj4lCsE898r5kmjvBHXcsoSI@y0mPdXd64i7lnAGUDesj1h7NK3NHYPDx49PRbHrryyf9od4scP1@S4pd0FlHI2Mtr0kepEpjXZarOe4XrSvWeysPfoQESANfRmcxcCvHACbum1dkgz2NBUUtdqQeire6sFxIfHjx@lF18@ksTe0LFHejLqvffsWQY/JHnv2UrvaOgH0Dr69nRt8IN9WU6uqL7@57HruOeKmNZhOtZBG4XK@JBtTnKrcKXZY713PBvr70PniRzcfcvoi2sz@UQ9NQbYCkllLaFoQyUVsZhPRhZeg7KtO@F7XXmeGGPklhp9Sey1dtUJSg45ycmtlh5umti/KsWQrL/g4LMFkrPXa2t0S11Jdf@xCZNleR2dn6l9KFdSWFtYywCrpoFN@/QtZox1X3kRQifBg1olGLcuEy8JI2DdEj5w5N13BGN37WqXmxCEzsWVDf5Mt2aqJdBpqpvEiyqExrVrN4J8UX@LuaZwIc8p7tu9cvouXDFPEho1Jm@J@NiJBNnbu3dwW4Ajn5Y3Q7375Dk5VF3cieNmwGiK9bdI8UIy@kjAcSvcBm7dAM5BzwFUyo34BuPV7blKnqlOz7Zm09vn1@iHpdi1051SQ1xoo0C6aUyNVX2Vxsa1DlevJrotbvaNhj1bkoOjO7T4iC6//KuynM3S/XfwLWeZ9ZaSCRo4SaBJneGmblGv44OQNWgot4jgkFypjT7Sp7jqhI0Gr1LqV/ZvxRv6vlJyfXdyk1/5Br/8DfFd80NHkhOz8g0ICzf4kYIYej@yzbOhLe6pju6unPFfkaCbMlK5ISOVCHf2Nw6nc4a@eb2Ij18m@K@VtfVY95z8eGh3jfwN61WWv/5dO@XhqQ5d0TKw/U87mH11xGcTfSXVHquvV3tQlnOy0gu4oT6c0E8frnsvT4J2QfjVrYHBdhsk92xvn9pu0NDCj6JXrzcwxvcn4/UpBiaJxzRc5etLgB@A8myfueQefgK3kNdXDALgerjV7uuEWxKOEOKmmw@Pd4Nq9vSZpERiXKTiw8MlZ/xI1Hv6LOLm6NPpOu1XmK5TJlf6LGJ9cpxfinar8eJ0BbHWf1cEcgcw5vC9ViBiXO@9Z9d5A@pxQ29kBj7vqdZi6HSpwHq2R78oXOl5OJvSZZMrS3rIVq2t8nO025aMQc9sGBC3K3U6uDNQp7OuVh7rH9JJCJCHiMfkE4bU34BLn@aHQQppkLUN1T5ZSEFLyX02HhrWdKXXaF0Yumo08ZG7uhnskmemfUYCZXg9e1BWI1dP9VWUXftRolDJ3SyO5a7IVuvKhZ3o4b/WFcm9dRLbFZ6Bix5u4iYY/kiTHgSW95XkrfDvPQvAb4fdM20cyO8Zk9HtwBRtOn07oHMD@7uK0LgdDA/AOBnajnU7aFCdqtV7@lsmYuOtIUczzX6LNHT7/duB9l37dqDHE9MzUHlZDfrEnpi4U8Aqv31nsNK9sdVotcSquM4T9xZ3h05yvT/w/ZE9cUEZMkLmGQYUPjK8JcegzkTdcKtz3RItO3kF73s2@Txuar6CFK/fsozee7AObnnmZoJz/fTL34Vx3Veg41nu1kb@2hhQy9s0OssY3Qi72H3uwLEtZkuu6x4XO9GtiOmhahq3MrRg5YNyyxoI7NCYPznN3c61QEB4sL7M3p9NF3rncu5NtrnEKr89BYgy0LRkcCoPLkWXc5HRP7bGbM0q3kXv/4X9kaq5yeh6sMiuNsF8srtOHogOKCx368@e3Ns9/uDw0Urfz6uj7mp@Hxxgodxny0b7kbXD18TbcNSVHvghPcOn4A5VEK3ogKuAu11cmaD/YPfR4eqefQj6LZQq7tAZGaVedMyJnuOqo0p@dTk@Dj4qvQ/sCs3rOpKHM90WJmvIxgS3VaOJaz/8uroX4M3QkR38rtWFJ7r3bOL0aXxsiwmQXKKHeLgZfzM5tiUL2wjDFYOTVhIJCxhccvlwu@iuHrjVfWITt3repDt4AOzFBdnwd80ADz7Yh8PfJwR3hDWsiY4bfbAjr7z6JkRTr8uFCtnG0@SqRM7SOPGszQrbeDOIrEk2z/09MKpVeU426oSv8sTfhSTcR5/tBQ@IcRdryBQRTmSy6YHPZrCDBqGHG5ELQmcGBA03CwabKEX3Eqr5e4xAmjbPDw8O958d7x4/f9bMtuf@HiRBLiwLYgt2OrqT6/GQeZ9uFhmzkyHo3jcmREdPtMEZBTfIF8HD3JazVl/K2iJT/DaG2Ty3LEmi27BIwhzSJ/AsNuqL4jI4MdxBjmkB@TvwVNmOKHRjFygjhpqncUKhVUl2VcRj1XUhW77/1bMPqS8enFnFozMxYn8zf2gVA9vu@TG6Orn9CmJ8sHvw6PnRPgkSuKg1Z0bPG9YrBXbWg7/NI4@bsph0v6K4HyQOZVWvxx/EgTBxMU6qdOMces4CbgkZD@sDbrnjh06RxCbFDxSMh4Ui/Y@PpXlcxE@tkgAbDxIVh2ihztOKgptiHkMlIfePDt7fPyKY/v371BlJhCjIMe7a8Rff67GTioK99IJDQ52Rr@FCabm20aviVjqaTmJ5WfH34@oR3EeS7TZD9Ck99YfWPDr8FzlGNEn3N@Oi@/8Em@Is9u3BkqMcIBqSnShE98MJjzIKT2TjOLpfJ9T3M7rd7JWdWJN0t0N2RCrbIzlETatecCoKLhMAjZz2uYZr4G48WA59e@JcaSS4BQbdeFgku3ieKp7aqtJDtyCxE8tjGzf6m7nFoIaKIa/KkE2aWHZEFx8BjG9tQCPp6gPDIq5lgNjmVclHUINxKr7KdmsShEb8WpAAdZWaBFS0I4BsiGCER18QYbyPO3C2HOnyV35JGtQImD0wf9U3T7P3wPY139YH89eZ@YWEFVSKXzuZKUxLNEG4M7OfA5YQrm/89Kd4xDKf2JTlk45zmo4XsjV4yLUCKZA7my1B2Gxm6zubKhDSezVtQXOWUvlT/f6w3zsYSC2eBxktL0mp8/Pz@IPUofGiQIpCz1CKr6azea6YezWd5@Tyq5OxXGyKr6ZtvlzPnLRbzTY5PPzwTedNkp@ezl5Bv5OACrb3lJfzfKxaIefbxVzspIKnMkIOT8hruE76BP/U/LoXMato7vah3sZ5Emu18DxkvsQD24u34U85xUu4GM9oNsSGuN1@8ybZVFVvCsKIYYzdXg9ue0gSipJ8RqCp3YVGxAJIpEXflIhwFUbTPpnu6oPBZF@dGZMH3o5YEsuiEmFMW4@/@IF/1T54/pyQ5@T589dHa9hYO51OCEKTmqeB4yOQRzJTUu2ohRieq/gXP9iYZ84PO1t/8clI0jfw9RRfX50/RvMzuXBnY@POvXv5fEZRFGY@/OLhz@/u7ubvZwqHzcJ2XshubP35n21sKMqWIm20XVdux5snJx/ySjbPi3/x3Xjn8PALrtvI/feP3zRkfJTgcUpKpIJXjshgxGcZbpkUCuRtr9jrmAxXbEZ/nVjgfr5B5MZ26X9@8@mrmBdrKNIHDry92KtYsRxjRjCALRfYTmON2BaCFeexmVSv18FY@p//EcI33gM86DPbgkejEOAqzmINoU6DXMQaRTDIigLx/j8ffxxJIfAzYCV12iKDawcYYrPJ50sKv92GK0WvLQ43MROykhTAWd7Q020il@/Kd9FigAVeFrxwTK0Vw5Nln@4Q8cVRGvqEtPh@Y0O6vyXAJY4lWVZasnwX2K9wJ1WvC9Cv0GabyxXu4gazSdobDmzPJvrdD5au2Af/JNdKNLUP/imvI7JnaLpjZ7hYcWPn5f1GA/Kba@RSjTS9/EZG21upzNv2DvCa4@HEMWw8orb2CA9bavDZssJnMpmdow4EIdMpklCYTsUOoiDspPsYu8QOYS7YnH1HVhfhaiAnaJPQnYUKrAs48jLehDbSfrkeLraP11/@57/89l9@k/6@Te//ijvAWT2jL6UA6BSaSwOunWpVazT4hsOft9DegDqWrZarZakzbyVSzUb7CMTady/ihVycPDNnmQ42G9JKtpo0fING2/CjR3sjtnBuMJdG1M33YMDUAd4@pUgsyGckXyHVCLkCx8WCxXRC87TRFnBMti405WKhLbBQzR0oHF4pVfhOOyZszoATKe2GUlCekp0Gu8hw0yU2pianFIOM@OltLPK28FnYGlGnWCMI1ljAfFY4P00VLtZsSm2d9hWNIKE7G9WNcrVYVaROY/1VW4TAi4Lqun7oxk5j4VUjfj0M6BkLa2bE7UW0JMJiIUEFJkthb4GDsgKmMZ36/zUXLa5cUeZrvknp8KQG9UPJCcqgw2dlaG07nVB434ZrA370D1doxecGdfGdKcj1a4NU5ZSSkwp3ivsKdr1XL0doNtKUMwrtRlpEDimIV2A46EuI1u12X2tdkExUtatqquypE3WqzlSvO@lOu5420fDkcXKI4l3HJ4OTswt22Q6oIgqxXEHejN3FvOWUCh7iDbpJuZyrKLmSnCsVc6WsUi7kypVcKZ8rlQBhrqTkKpW8ouSKpVyxnCsWc8UKHpQOMEWAySGGUiFXyXGxN80NcsT425Skg6uVvvV6LlKOhhc12HgLgj2NgeAE2nyGi/0zXA1ZkUkKOscsPEAipEai0B/kcE81Jm6GIzEQ9s7bb1LNNykSLS3BTzO8xM5OOy3M500w12r@f6sRGmv0YibIanueTm@9aIAM9KLRTAPKFz5KUSAUqdhpkPYW9Qpj86Pz/bfaIEYJ6a3mVt3eo7dIm6LQBpRbS8nc2aH1agdCNjahySfT6U1B2GgCnqbfGwEw1j4/P4CpnQBZ5fz8Z7xJPG/Hi/bO1hawlfnWvDFvbs3nW1vw36LPuf8G1/nWtT99La41MAv/NrKkVlNqtKSWz5baYBelBrqIUgsMDXgDXDOnlNvYEaKgI7b/Zf7FzOIZumCS2yKkmoulSCqGG6DlYiku9vLy0/8N79blp99HoZXAT69ysXNCuJiUqhDqRl8VkNweW@Qxuyww4x1Y0QUdGo/R0WIPC1VhSXopkqpA9eGEXC4mRezpO3a/g99Ri@QlgALY/kCH9hKwWcIr5SLfScszhcS2@GKJctafu3bF4/F/9VKplOJM3cYPgV@6rvs4kspFOgG4pmRlQb5osP2u2YEEP7fq@lc/t@7iYhcVgjRKEEYXLgbVKCZJoCZyscbWCFeT4mE@Ap7KeFr/UHi@K@zZo7HqUX0cB@tAKqgf7NcrlQbqSfrmIW06qfspeMrw39@ATJBWH0Bb/bo2Ahm81c8VlBaqpe@qoJ4DTxO6r/D36DX@yLGGv6NX@CPHr/F35OGPPO7i7/gV/na7@Dse4e/eK/w9fo2/5wP8tT6Xy8k1fvOckictV@T55pSnZKpBd9Zofc5zZlX9VDUTvLKtgMyZrLFyzeUryVjrc2zgpOqfT4MrfHXNq6n1Sq1bV3xQf3kS@oiGGxz5mWDfilcVksQBi1ylYDsCTqHDAxzSuYpsO/GffOOTT@L1elyI0/MZ8uAmdBGoS4HACiHzLCV4SBukDwrddeO1nfjnmnRwqlBpN9GzDR5crE425U05a2a1rNyVu2AwSNYh2WF2KPdkqrdldZKdZWckO7LlHph0@GXBZGT7JDsgWStrARj4gsnrZD009eE1gF8fEDnwM3CZVlfOagQiMlFIpeemyR0Mmb3okHeHtutlxi2uSeKEf6mDAi7KYlYsGm08RaPJv3zZklJtpVImIlZysdN82Yq3@RaPeywrlTzpzvSN1ksepJIszxoDupCY64JWX4tJrZbECgDIRkt0Pu909p/c73Qk7B5bRG@kd9LA7nd26sD@/dd2rFHbblVp7xH0IDFpa7vVyAloLqahb1DAjTzUTd3KSOnPeC0Qw7uxQQnQfnn2EpSgxBmqQmen8DoLDB@04NFhShL1ls4@aEWs1AAXwkrSByswLBkg1ZYDagNZyH7wB23yn@tv/Mv6P35OkiTRbCcT5/OtBL2S@Esmz@fnc//ZSCYSviWxBT90ADsGOZ830EiBzsHUTCTbyfmcucEzkdxiCBsQzVaDhl3AQScTC6Ok0bJH4p/2DVH7VyteIy/5rS1Hu2jVKDfIZyskxr@sEXUx09BqTbPZJHAsfwN4wSKb6gUdlk3WNDxdcbPblNt//l26yf92kgIV8rWanCLMouSVWi0f2ErlWq0cWDYTicr1q5HdlougO@XzyWStBpbtAG0WrBC2Sd6kSZ204Nm@e5dFUlYuLgKcuXwxncUZnlotiKkA0equqjH2DXLowVO6QT5wi0KMIFMg/iB1IktP2EC2Huer/N27Cf8M5e3d5N27SiV7cRG6jMfgJC85dTo9w@l00D13ccF3eDo7UCmAPVu@uJCzlbQcJ0nbSTzBg3AhroQgkztKg0ZbAZ6t5Evg7aegsLVVzDcaxTy4FMsQEDLFOHaNxPl4jY@d02zI5RLjY3wNnUkMGjT0mu75PEZLkuQLyQTwwCRIlfMY/hxkl6y7KhSStXw2Gzuf8wxYrlQYdJLki4lyuuL/6htJ0gCRif1Q7sul86lSagckaPy501UXctTauV6X5/VzvYrHK81rmn/MKH6Art@9m6sAacrZGLk/wW0wMi3OZ8d16JhQ@oJHi4vH0@TOXQ6/znfi1doOLVm5XCCxeI05CnFg66QMNJaUVEEuI004o4/bSoAIwclUF90gG5xC3/jgKkxD3UBH0H2jvI/@uR5cpEe6ZIAXGaDuSQxi0ouYhPnTp6aFQDa7fN/QSsPiFbro4cWG3HOFHKulcfJoohk47HX4aHdv/zijbAkkpjzY3csoz57fi8loLSzs1DuH9qP93ftPn0OAw0f7u8/23z14f//5Ibi75Gxxhb1E0FeEfUbEtMJ@Rj7gPnJeq7qu6hNd75xNJmevyEeG0TGgaM0J5M0eOMTVO5ClsbrIXg1uzXDVjz5SnTG9yOV3vnz5nV@4/L1vXP7ely9/79s/@fTbX4b7e3B/g72/8UeVAj5/8umv/sHl7/4eOP5XuP8U7h/85NPf@Jjd1P5DuP9bxO2H/h2BYzcHuL72k0@/@d2ffPr134T7d/z7N6/fv/KD1fe3v7T@xnDf/IObYb7xH@H@Q4YrgP3G7zI3fF@D/10G9/XfvPz1/8T@f@7/0Ph7l7/@Q3z4ll/@zT//b5ef/BdFKf/5v7/80jcvv/TJ5Ze@evmlf61c/sa/l7PRxx9cfvuP//pP/vCv/@Tf0P/36PMP3@Z/@Zu//Ff/@1/9H3/1J/79A7j/E5h@8Ff/BZrr3/3xd/D/zT/@uz/9Dv7/19//uz/@1t997d9Rw28xwz/8zh@x548@@fKPvvRrP/rk0zXPL9/4/PQt3D/9Z3B5@3S@DZ63yddndfn0Z0rPP4Yai1igDkDN/cXL3/gKVN5fJ@Tyy9/DjzTgXvP/niJTmO8x2/8PDMr1PKNPFkxwf@vyy99AEv0vQCL4h/T6amhZ8mGWry4sQNbfXhHoF3/y6a99l9pierVBp5ywly4r5XQKFJpUpeL31P5sFAT5yjK2EIEf01eR@yz5fRX51uV3Pr787r@@/M5vXX7na9g/C/lKZjcjyLdM5QFg4S3gELD4NnAI@CHE30nTEToh/SHYNj4slHOWZdU@/PBDrnMh4ddAOxfkQ/iRD4OLMC/8Wsj3CvzQHT8fIuDefPmyjfO/ETdJZsglhb19L1zZAzEJyp30tiQrzEu/kDZZKFIDh1w514okXer3U1X4EXhUq6nzjLDdAiGPBp1zepAl2ce6IRFZzeRSORUApTyDI1VrJ5tPl1KqCpprGvGmqZiTCoSvQo5M036UU3@OGN0BaJqixilhw/xT6j3lpnQqGf4lQsokR4jF/jWOpKlERC88FC0wUoMfLpiGpkauANGkF5MIVBokTBBLMRc6uU7jzYP2QWfm0lPQtsGAI9/gdQ@E/Xo9jQHrLIlgZZlplAlNSjpdh3xjaBYm0ykjiuk9igVC1tNHpJOqT1nANOJrBORIc@h0xMsKny7X70OE9el9grgQOUX78mW9Ua5PG4juDaNOepq@R9OEyOrpaeMN2OsUJ4TjYvffQFLK9XS6UcYIMZOseFDBxkIq0MzRvOPMLisDeOPyqu0dQu7wcpln8ycbSDAGjc/0AhoBARz8W@mUnx36D4z0TlGCb9Co/FgI89@mYvA2k4wRAPAKgiiKBG5ctLBNdsB7ylClabTwSjMMaVojaA0IHQilCZem5csIBPGDMz0flihKvgaaRY2gk6NxeJwcXQmT5TanuMrpnPhScNY/I3XOqQCTz@a48wvVXwW1qZI5OBU5hKBx1lOf@cLEIrE2Nze5WIPP8U/pvG9akohzUqVr2aDlUh2pSvhihUdnnS7sY8R7jMvLMxw11zCb5PLj78by2VKM24zT86gJi4jcSbN7ZydF7gBZ6TviNqVLxoR0zs7bMUbGrXSaVyDShg22FCVhmmLjXpBYHf/gHqMVi8TIoeoYbobLUJaYgZdYj6E3efr0qZ9e6vCizqWhxSk5Ge045zeZTCC43sP59UxGFDNiJuO/RfqmDqJvEKmv/xY3kfQkqsvJpTIeRGtpQ6QL9@bNG6gbHNKiegDKNTOSupIvU09Cq8EUF3OpowzHtocwzVmwZlTJVzg2EkHkYp6QBK0RcCUJLo5MQNVOcmyFFatewZWIK2VQlxESSkxMABhDU5SRJ7FVqPQjIVIoLVkhZVErji@yMW2c@A@Xf7L0JcqFZOC595TsPX38eP/J8bjdJpxODz7WO2PH1nTXTaDf7pP7rPoqlWIy1mxi3o@rCvJIbr@axWqcPrh/dPCsShjF/KJL0HzU6Jy5T5eKzMXG4w@2Yg6Oqzs6j@d52fwzfFYXpEgoFeDfyViDi2k6KlxQT/EPd40c6QOsvo/dwT17ShLZDM9n5CKqw0mcAobk/Lw9IbgrJdvCArgDrtQTIb@Y8sa5EJlZQocGOVI4ZhBkaiC5SjkwlJhBLhUR4Ck7EC/HNZ7tHwPm46dEVrIiObK7BiSq8SGZijSdR/ZItzPCnIZGjnRsjGyEMOumbg284SYeMsy3snyEQJvNbAZ/Si4HTzlfzMiFUntjwzwXEE@LVplzXIc4B@u5gDR5By7CvcORd8AJLmFOOHuM30mxAfyDpzVWefHjX5KA1D/zHF4uAF9IcjgX4ePjxtGrBkSHdrY8qcfFNr74RY80GvtP7gsHD3DQYTokwSJGweiJQ5FWnN7E0anvgJCe8b6BR7@JPcMdm@oMGjHQK9UAgng4uRqbz@d9wHnwgCgNhVpZ2B4@5xp16YJ5PlU5Agy6z8XuBuMsXOlutVp/I@dLkLZq9U1OUThw4FIgVRj9DahtdEFKSmI/3qrn5WxaDmYxSJLn@ZoLicrlylKKi8k8D69cLsfRBkS4qs4RukzpTbZeF3wen5fpKiUOjyFQp3UlvHzY6Z0FbC7LYNEHPMjAc0g28CsxP98WdAuQFVy3S0@7rfkcJXv3bg5Hm3L5bJh3QklD5lCkm7l8DgsJ3MC1HcuX/OkxyF87xpm6R3p1MMdamGHWmOUYT9CG/C9XznKxZgyaNtdsN@v/3//aTa49/Zf7B7I0m3VuChwyevvOCEPfZOnHcY/tp4v/06ejqPXG/@ip/fipPbLhDz3hY2TgtcW/Vluy3vz3OScypRqIwpynT6E6wS@fLYD1H7798d//@n/@@3/7VREv3xY6/MO3v8Xcf@dX8fmtb//9t37h77/1b6nLr/z97/wb3@sffuf3yX1o47PXKvSf3OXXP7n89I8uv/@Dy09@@/L7f4LW6P/T/@B7ffKthSOY0eXK/1vkb37l//zb3/7qX//g47/91g/@9rf@@Ecff10pyz/6@Jf@9rd@8Nd/@jUC9h//8Cs/@vhrf/NLn/zo418EuOj/xz/8auD1pdARzOBy/Q/ugJf7F3Mhp8MJfDonveVvAtqg68ebciXf3gdm0STtrWB/0AZAb7HPmQhuzFLnsaglz2BufMPVzb6Iq7Lr/Na4kcsq/Ja/yXiDvK9byIz98I1evWdr9Ij1Wk808Kh7/HSGhcvn@Zpt4dZ@9WDiF3rs5Pmgfka/9K7p9YGIm8U4lmpC8K7dm4muNwNRS7NN26nHQe2Mg7T6vmGbtL6AebdnWygJWnUd1BIcbN/O5fJVyJ84tsfbSqEkEKEpZ0F8w1suZ3rQoTjb0I9VlcyGvl0qVXuiZuqqs12oFtBbC6frtwvZ6kD88PGjh543PgLJQ3e97XwFAuCGa7g10na5WihAG@b5dJPG2Mazo1lHLWxsQMemqz0B3jib7wpKuV2l8dfr8fh2TlYEuZrLljk/swuCWTVLyMvF7WzVi5KR7JuGZTsZnsMjbsNSwAIcyo18Nr8lwRtUbQmXFoBY0iC7@kBH@YGWnLwljbFOgBFAVTB2wVjYkrpgNMBY2ZIMME4aOTm7JU3AqDXyMrhqrJZgaRCjV4c4MWdpTHYGq0tmKJ/7HXXVsi19zlUzasY4pyVX7ff789R5emHh1HOB2aBM54Ka6Z6H1poQgauSSUYwFp7govahipz7KymqvFIo87VmbWEvFflae87tjPSeoeLx5K3s@fVQRRCgGNYYRNQi3Lzq2LZX7ep929EXgDm5GACyBF0HyPPzMLpWFmM8vx5dMQI0PV9QL6Ra17S1Ez8meh7nqrjyBX7OaT45HL03ZxFlqpnAkQWllQMLC4st9uIFF0sdvZ9rNKB2nudLSr6QLyi5YrFQUkBYrOSLhTJUjmwxW1AUYBH5SrlSmkPblKQ3MXqEH9k7D9pslR5ckFCrbHvOZpsk3zwxzPNyTmBMJpGsgXQRe8PF7hy9rzQa60ezEiB4v68IjXquUAFTDk1KjsoiiiIoOSEnC3IO/7cYFPy/PbwCfwWfECqncMe4ac8TkHlB3LfII9zzw7PJsW3T73/u6doaiL2hSjcI2nNs1/1HwNxTrRPmdd9gO@WGXg9VPOrOHRnecA3E8/EI9/vRnX82DPujLiQQeToDuAcPx7TtVQAl8vxwTS4fh3vTAzHY5vQAfnTw7sPjyPt4f3fvIVck954@uX/lVfCBCuTR/oPj0FpivkHQQoji5/cfPbpq9V/5p8@P@hPbwZt78PR5fvEInfCzKS4P1zJQ6EyR@A@0osiEkj3ZABU7MMgcfrF1N18hd31jobgwZtH4AfsmzHDDj7rYZ4VV7jj4UEwlyOi7OtHYtk449ki3XPRHAeRShePGxLLPSClLerZpqg6x@/0NcByqLunqOiq1pok1EaM@sx2zd2b09A0QNSGOioxno2MiuIeAZDTR6EYBoFTgBr7QN1sEZ@@75kQnkzFZ6wgvdEKjYwyGIE@c2QEA11VVAvdnvSC8Hr28mx08Fgd1u@ZjXgfnYtzuUxytqMR4fo/nH6qeWnP00gvS2J9CTYV2ozqzTDmT470CP8C5XtP1es3UBDSkjY18mSit7F6WLoWaqXVZqnXrRC5eNLbz9g7qT6iQpzp6rDyoV91CUd7GnrieTe/EbPehXq7xvGplgHFmqi6ORTywnV6V7FsG8I0HcPH8CzIVOziK2qpZOKpBcFwGKlv1b377ez/@s2@hvEfu246m4opj1GAJ1Ud9RVak4ydKpVwoV3JKOVOulPMFuVgoZGQlI5fKpQqkLyuX5WK5UJEz5XwFBLV8BXwLlZKvBktSiuyaOOyVYaqulKoCekvDE8G36FCMOGxwMbYohLxOqEkSU0P7hPA6hOHJrjXQTcCBI2ge/VwxZdShAydyluRKBDCrRCOxBw/2spjxe2jBpXJ7WZ7voaVQzmZL93hepz57ZZRFeZuFKeMmjLzHLNnsPSjLCUOA5xfw/BAt@0WcAuF5Ay17u4zAfbQoGB7ATpgPs5iBpQRgFlpAL6cIXoXYAGyXxZOnCd1HC0aJPg@Yzx748fy7QXLQ54iBMQQPg5zu7vL8AbPs7qLPHs12gSX082jZpRfPO2CBhsbzAzAMHGjiPN8FIzY3ntfApM1UcMNT2HGLe8tTeX7GyIME4vkphVa1E57vBO4Yzft@agpI3Sq1yCzXO9RSwR/PK0GiESwXWnI8nw8tecjbw4fvq0Ovpw/YNXPYW4OcPnyYU43pZP9B9913u4NB15nt7r97hF57ew9BtJlNnO6g6wfsduCyIdTeQ0U9Gc2uXpDrg06nqporvT7f6eRV64pXZ9bRMYUQ6hWkzL8GGNGoswdeew87O@qqRT4UYQc5zQjeXbzujeB9T@0yr@CiXvQ97Xb5GjQDUFtaCQ41LVyng83zBDi3lRmpmmPX0D6tkyxdDT1rFrPtGvUgI1CVsrU5@vcT@FRxlDp5PmtO69l2fVov@Yts@wm@NVUKBp/ZGG3LlUJ1Q92WlXx6WsUvre1@nMQFeZsk5Lup1yTxJLmtgMK0wbe2twW@Kbe3i6UXyNyq@NhW5HI1n1VIkllzpSqEycazhOAj2Sy1t0uF6iJwqZRWJaVaKoEQCPTxQJTo4rhwhyQSZ7p6kkxi0unAIuSHZpzMaKaNWj8xzUzrLJFklqxN63KN7fNMslewJRI9PFRgouHuD4QhHQDCKWhMuEAswcuVMg9pkKREEpjRfD5nxDnPZ8vz83P3/Lw1D1mlBKbF0O4HXzg@OT7@ELgVyCqzDBVHG/6g6KGjI8@r@dZ3H@6JB08DG54XID5AMdl2xD3kcUs@TF4OnI5BaRIfQgcPCnPgBmE8xzbFfbqSGmTtwCPYX0P09@4Vjx8u4Xk2tM9YzBDIrdENIPEbdzxOwegRtd4Ak9ojCZoqoibPqGjRaTTqnfpIH429GWQxCPV5Qs8aWKA5cFna6XEwuJceDX7ed@yR79GpZ@fQ8U1jU0EguyD5TZwMYOzUiSC/HNm9l0paq/XwPIV79XuIptaBdxdUft1xbIcHjZWv9bet@sRy1b5@qDv44f7B000QeXDfi0Sf6MlN0tpH6D3UsOZCwyHWIo1PJqOEKjS6yWUnnEgIHZBMiS8E2T/HgXRIOc/Pa/06SbwA0FdgdzZJoifeS27na0Cxe6STBKfsy/7LPlFIMV@jClECcUETpJRCCqjJeuPzIKkx1CekWoXU@EV@AlgxMkAMpUF91OTYmNe0ukkSApkmKY3ytUG9icEv8LElgIAhCM2LNs4DfIBawqsJdJ4NaO61WUytu5MuPZGHZLuyki3WpuAml/K1IZS3@mJac@rjiaPXTLD6MweE5litAW2BhIDm9UXi8isfJ7eEQp251SiqC5RbOmKnPq1ZuMcn1JR6rg4e6WY@mymUQaQplDIgQijFjFzM5DL5jFBCV5AfMoUMOIJCBsJRwkzwhPCZ7DQryhlZlzOJ7Euj9zKZOUlkgQ6UeMmMZ@9bkxFBFygyrK3UDm81mVZSQKKeTdQtgVZeYDI1zBfQfkjGRmZIMR3pqskCJAWSSyXMzQQCbR5PxvvNdrW6Px1/AbwSwqvtYrqUTb9OJmuJjWTd1V/RWZZ7BlQQFYiLnIlmf7wBddqfXSHuZNSEUgeTXFKqzWYX81rKZnLZHGTT6FwMtvgG385kN4oylNmcjqbLhHGW6IQCSE7cwm3cQY3B1KEM5YpS40Qcx4@Re86EznDkyopQkQqpQpbNKjAU3NhnkUhbkmjx/mcY8UQ8XlLi8YV6nYzXcPp2g1/Mp1Glmy6hTcSBZZP4XaVQ3OZBAOSrfEXhAWzBcTGVJBukPEX2VN1VHZx54XDQguRBaT/n5ufzrQY3Fbn9kWEaaoZYhoZH2xnaicihNJshXWNA@qqHbVnkdiG3B1WRewYaoE5NzX08loCw8HTLCgzW9hFW6ayUN5wNdVCLRG5GJ@k88borlBLBdxDVMgT5HPcMdzzYUl7gr/Ti8e5T/D3YieF3D2Tnc@BXAffyi8fPnz5/@oB@1b747PSzXDsckejHDSC512I1OpqOKxcgGibfv/21g7PWRNrAD7dJWhTEBt0SYIfF0vI3p5E2CPmsX1@ktxov2LuF3/IBao7uid4kbboqWjdQgSfvqyBQbpM4FLnqjJqKkms3lRKIJdB1NbMMVFHkGqSiE6NfoTagfk/PIdFb6QZ@@P95MpupaSHI@l3SGKQ3s8osdtrhi5Uc/Uq905CzJ2QjfjeFB6ULJHZ6stFQUun4YTWXjt@P5/Kx00Rrs5GWZ3GJpNLKrI9rvHCtkBQHOEVP3cml4s/T1fIgU5XT@FTgWY0TYSO208nsJCsuR2syiS0ReKOyW98dHO36kx1kd69RVmb@hgWxFx2@XPKT2NoEkinpFztL4RsgC73AKc8r5UZ@hmsHF33Ha/HYeZzE4vP4vBlvc7EdurWCwrZWILFwcwVcqeWvFsjliyQZI0nfVqrE3ESSrp7wp@s/F9@JxXFWnLjuG6jUtCxo0w4@VP/8SwUYTcyyAwd74uHILohShQLO@cakl2P3i0o59/jgqXXfeaBzsdbGxYaN8/mkxjOUPHljvfcFQsZQYnHSqsem9bw/ayo3GoK8peCWVCVSBSGgLxeF7EWDcbMG9Sgq4HP5ld/MT7fKYFeyMtgVpZBWGg05BWJobHz56fc9Z0bO99/ffUTiOAf74z/7rlL68Z/9Pl1GHp/TeVklV4oBJBrlYil2fj4@PwchcM78CrF27NrSujaQSZLVSiklQl2QyioYOlKMkRTE5ZKcjLlCzP@IoFgQEglZUpKpXDmbBJ8Lf9ufhJItgzVYHEGd@GKBT8b2j4yCIu9sbUPOtnN5pbYBxSqHO2aQ8Lelu5UYFys/fnlBCFi0Rm8wMBRqkiS/Hb0RyNYbYQveUMJvhA3yst7A9YEybrYRTLWn8JN9XPgSb6SlVJyArk0azXlt3k7T6Xo6BvIiZbWuEKO1gR9@LjulLPjpKZf@dJ1aqYML1sCmpz5y@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@ebFWoQHJIDCSnZWhRrbqRFZKSRImXoO0azRRdGOecHiiNb0jKh8GnnNI4U9jwSldwKyOo6Phfr29r5sXo4uQ4C4BJWxCN5/0hipjBj3dNEaGf9I9Mr0DLwgdhoKsGCaF7hsOqMJ0gV2wY10iJycx2GKHP5oO@pmckif4sVohiS8aCqEJvFXcQc2PZ4OKr5oNBeqObYtuueYha8LPBaFGAI@CCJ7Yns6SPbHO8Eg9v2xo4GiKIJeg6WDNxxTTLeRsS3dZWFyp1nV09SSgTYboA5Foox5RKiRBK5qFizasEF2SBqIJ7oIGhTTumvoIkvRM1@l3625VkgYg@E26OA8uPTagXg0fGND9WK50nxFYOjNODOkYt7QW7D5@3k6RAxaQFbH5sbVuoGxOzB4xbfuEmMaJziY5EtHt6/A0j2IGlJ8MUHZxA2GrKPYquQwOhMkZBgV3CV4lZixnImE3ErPk9XdO3kh0sEQvaA9mQKmY@qlqRehLrwvOH0xxZy5Hd@urE1QeEmAXQ5YLLZNtfBXHna/iSRFo30skOVq@LgTBkCJOno0TfIxPiu7YNDxq5MaOfkpwMITDPgaYptbxk4CtGHL7Du0AaNuDloU76HlOFUouDSlxegkNmp7P4C1yh@QUDgEhZgRlCQAcWPT1ZezgB0ExH67Xg4IR6YwR8hVonaMe@OEOXX71w/BB7UYz3c9wUb3Jho8OOx0aV52wZhFYChELtg6szzTrG@BZhBSuSMlGgk8D2jSf5BnqMPzV4Ky2c5SXVMl1TBmCGHxSAxYqKqjIcugGuYuz73DhyD3VZQekYK2HSn92dibSzSInjiHqLp4H59qWakrjgQHisC15@mjsn7xtaNI4wLswCewYSHE8HG9PUaitV@7O2Jvj@m7dX7qaiPfdOHaOp3jc2WB0ivoVJLjv0gr1wKBHJWoJfyUtq39KO3Me1L8q1j@hHJ8jEkIQzTQzy2gZQJbpaieZ/lmv5nuc0gYJyKEU9cARt3B1AsvIDUzGuB9C2B7y0dCra57Q1QWAiWczBouoWQ4DyFlg9e1jA1e8W/oZ2XUcdZag/kmExgqcmFGxh8yg26c@YMQ948/ZfqLGtDlrLwWfhsGhUwtXEQEjT2DPdSNStrks@k@Z/xT8p8x/uog0iLY5bTORDJ3mmB2s9bh0P4BENLMAZs42Yl34UMwghxOZoUDI2ZIbLvHV6jR0QG9mg3KsBxUD6sQYCK4npOaLVrPVtlz9LNVOSwOo7DwlBJQ4oG62KU3PeqEZqW@emmPbXXKC7oOKN3660Ukb@rWB1RXMY1hAtGIwehm4eeZg5K9uYgKBn2HAgHIYeKJosOsljGQt3M2YekLFafILGrOENf3EtKn05Xv5biAuMdIzwkYRtSOI0D3MEiQTfEjQctjpnwF3@MCxASaAFeiBhcAiZyTejgMlrzQVxmtqtJAiqRKEIJlAdhRX61ezEvhDUTSveEWyOffLP5r8jc@c/D60i9WppxWWdRg1LtpUcJ0@iBB@c6FUJY16pFwhBVJKNXUHeq59Jp/6vTVEk5ICNYPFg1lwzwxPGyYiha8lWfnQ7RJ4i6@GVWFWr0MWZ/X/t71vXU8bWRb9HT1FBycDssXNsZ0MvszCgBPWckw24GRysIclg8DMAGIQtmEy3t9@iPMe51X2a5ynOKcu3VJLCJskc9lrfbPXnlhI3dXV1dXdVdVV1TwteV4okjLB/WqerLZQjCDr8wICMHKx1RxZba5Xmx8e8sIh5iuq3WlIzgnJOVfh0vMVSF7KaqA9VdX2gsNzCdIpRhAkAF6et1EQgyYJ4dm3Dvpz/HgzmqBWpdoM1hziAslDKGIjn3UuY1tvaUhri1YEADLiEoAuXyReMKILXj7t//LXKCalWqP4l2QDXiuAwWgJ3jdYB/KZjHRgEPgTW7QPwNxNbLWMRJ6OCvB/Of4vYamX6r/88stcuGQ@/DJnRf73u7y8RMpqE1STPvK5HVyQjcBSoZss3rqgDQZ2CM1pQnuFh0Xhd7AAjKkYa3AjhJIixe1B8wLZF3iKM3vgR5KigpUTliipj/FCYyXOPUrCTI0Iys91B3rGxThh7mt54JWVIdgYhTipnlbEJgWL9EhwVkJzYppgKYXReDoYP4QAne6R5I2TiKwWz70C/Ac4WAokkInsFymijfkobkSRq5tei9IuyYlAfCpSeR0bRLAHyvEYj9etxHNPJKxvoKKJjFupnZhGOKG6PCYJ1QfkvMk4BbWsRDqToKrwDpZWfGeGQfBo4nuFMKCMsqlSxFChwFvcMnTjiDOHroz7Dilmdjb/Krf3rUG9G1sza9T69tLa7BwmBCxB9njk3Uzvuj/13evbnhiKyY9X887il5@F2N3BEFex/Q2HMOb3DrMUcvVSYPTrtzlKhS8R/I7CMTGVdUaZtJOCkuBzXMBTQQn5BfkqFFAmjHCp2BwpLkSjwuxw1Nq7PBzDIjxqjS/30awx2zqcbeW3Uvjim7yJmXmwZqrTml0CXe61WbRpvLZBq6FrNYtXHh1@wp5mhMwFM9ghPTyFpcMLvD1mOABBn5jpjhRSGV8HygowbABRvxvbqPZQs6fyFj5J9R4qZUQNId8NUCjxP3h4x5xHOywesc4wszuAxOMukDAosTrssi@2WWl3BPYIS8Gu3deRwBFHcwxOfz9de8aQqesN7ir1BY1jeI2yQMUVT/1hpy4Yxn/cDDo/lV6L7VzuZT73Iq@RDO/ORQRzmRc7wXYFRFIfttHNZze/Yxgld7JgBz7YzBHWThoBWuIUleP3oJc5t8547BjF4ZA9/Ty8YcCZ3jrdjGHUnS45kV7dEEVQjbtBcoFW695MO5yW/mowtqcL5Au8M4MS2cPkx7/ooTgCVacnL6ezDLSCgEI2GszYVuLeDvD6B9/y03OHQ/cOCdZBowvTAyuNHNjjjE1ThFFCYilcSN8f3XgznNJoNUaA9hVebdvxyTCGza8DI0MmDGMIoMhwpzU27kYwgfY6QxtVrUwcAtCQRgGFAHSte9NxHsTBICQ@EwchO6bCM2w1Mll3arg0V0Y2qrYg1wUEplGhahruMMDNN9WGaNROmh@K9YqA53f12vtquVIWxx9F801FlGrvPpJ7rnhTOy1X6g2BwaCl2lmzXj0@b9bgRaLYgJoJ@mAUzz6Kyvfv6pVGQ9Tqovr23WkVoAH4evGsWa00LFE9K52el6tnry0BEMRZrSlOq2@rTSjWrFnUqqpmBPVE7US8rdRLb@Bn8bh6Wm1@pBZPqs0zbOwEWiuKd8V6s1o6Py3Wxbvz@rtaoyKwY0a52iidFqtvK@UMtA9tisr7yllTNN4UT08jHa19OKvUEflQL48rgGXxGLZHbIn6Wa7WK6Umdih4KgHxAMFTSzTeVUpVfKh8X4HuFOsfLQm0UfmPcygEH0W5@Lb4GjpnpB6hCoxL6bxewZMopETj/LjRrDbPmxXxulYrE60blfr7aqnS2BfGaa1BBDtvVCxoo1mkpgEGUAu@w/PxeaNKdKueNSv1@vm7ZrV2ZsIgf6jg7RylIlQtE4FrZ9xbIFKt/hGhIh1oACzx4U0F3teRpkStIlKhAVQrNfVi0CAQsal3U5xVXp9WX1fOShX8XEMwH6qNigkDVm1gAYCJ7X4oQqPn1GscJ8CLH4FZDcW5Fg2nqJ6IYvl9FTGXpYEDGlXJLUS20htJ8ww62GoC2gCvxHPskS609ZZf3TroFLYs7cXLf/75U6lWroiEOjdMBB/OYdd5FTmY0r/BTuN/hJ@hA4Cuc3XTb@PVKCix@9VYqBp5fQtzIZgYhX1hPHBWLWU3qrCx0W6/L7aL9deNdtu01qkZQuOxGpTQE4S1B0qZso8YX4Y2NBQqCwWm@0GIUEffoDjYc6aWYEdkKsnU/4Y217E9Al0xm@06shqaQhCwEkthD566IwHAurg0khUW48aDJknqod8DyQ5UMaXAZzpteI0950KuB/@Mfw1@8OagvYDVmUXpbLbvzBgNUFBVM9wIGZjoH2nfAe2LJHnPcX7qp3J6c864a2bwHiH0kJR1qOzMGQ77KfOR6ldOP1I9Ha1PyKJRU@W99TjMgLULZEw@B5MkE3JcMlPqWQr/ac/oj6mwYQsaGkqoKTLBS4Uo9Q1Xb@UukaxsKASJmgcZZb63xe@rH1DJzW3v7Efev/Hf89xCp0H0L4UNr0X1LunPm0suABOMLJtAkoG0N2azWh0Qy0ig9AvfQcFrLMT3IOFefe3Qvg4kAUH2Bm@40@rDbjwdzHXsYR1@XS@@PT4/OYGlE7HdebX7cm/f8A8xv7f470dshzw86Qx3Avs4yGn0SZslJRB8aKZo7vgB@xMDZ7NYEMM61KDRS7Sa@ZcNsZDA2SNIljp4Qbewehh0YoMS5YzpgiQyZz41FL/GzkzJAKlQV03szciek4hvg6xEPCAPTYcLGrU5/oOw/emvprjfIclAksXI5xU413jC614CK9FJW8@9GfMxCBbJJBQf86G4TwO8PUnkC/IYkX5J3tZGEQRbHGicrzTsVBOQeBrFQkg9lLy7oYl3ZLWVyiWdxcKb7yW/weNH6S5AzgO2NyvOGkDGE78m6sCBois73ZKQLzHMDo@oVUsHAi0IpkSK5p5UVX0zqzYbCBWMc0XrVBjwvm@VjTaJinDyb0nQt5lT0RSKcPYlx8rfwLlx3ZFQ9pU1Vv5WNj7BsHyTMVPtzm/DUEU@@lZBRc4Qmb6KHgT/T6RJDPwD0DgBekAtzaViLUoSVKYVqK9ElMGdMmJolpOAmvqrjwGYe31grv2OScvQnFwJkARydBbqxUdyIumlYgiATG6iZ4E2f7uuwxdGXtugOv0tYcrqaIMZd0aTlJB7hdoqluCm9y4tErssZbfBH6YwyTArtAZPoar4GytuVzTrQWWKqPLiuZdgcKaypmY38TwjmPDEpUiRvJrsAWfl5CxT64A8uNI2nK5//gRi6f1Ki@Cm0ByOQmu/tKopQgHoI8RnuZ8Ub@iKztD1nIj/Cqfyb5JPAXrvW/KKO@kAgJ4G6OKEcJ53hbw9zpnd4QYxZOjk@BBAE6nn5HuBjfCxRCA4qOXWzABpaVu987GfE/Z3GvbnY44xoZ8FoUpk2MdEYjjG6/@AZ@imYfHWXgDKw/W6zSyW3Wy4lrhzKJKHzRKyPoZfdlx3CqKjjf0GHK3BwsyID9Lo4Iy9m6n0BoH9bDCVFgkl9EMzM7qinWiB2wzHbhBq3gDkhhnaXJA/qEsjxx5LB5HBPL0nUsC8ikePkIXJrWW@lRepg@DLAdCEnLyIiAdiD1OTUSkmqHTAcoiCA89XLmCWuNzOgcgF0@/Onf6Eez@KQOOu0/X9vDSQ8EINUnVMHjOdGXd94npk0YChQAuIT4k8G9Ku7M5Pdyh5wx79UrITCOj4KhH4GqEnGPXk89vxmVRCxYYCxpWtA/PtpWEwkUrb0tHKd73Kb@8SKnEK1/1KZYx8r8ImcZG4GPtLSkHe0flciY74xOum//QRn/iONufwuYezB96g/VyKoIgwyqxos11e5wg/PK/4MHCmXd0mCpJM156g@Y1UH3dMvKhMh9KJomPPPGcBGkAnO5hnCUY79Xf3etwuuUO7P3AHNuhpGF4x5xUPHxf0iAPWn7p3HkUWc@YhrVB3ETyTNVweauNv6bGDP4ODTm/mTFL6Echsuihi1gXUYugYH89a/f2K@HsSPXH26@zsBpX8OvIe8BvvGnTT/ZV1X@TjKvNpAQKQC9xR5HSGjskd9Hk8VC25k5R23KEKXD1UQMPxSqSFrX2@X4nxt0AiOuANYayQWTry0DuBmtlKjFvdudUlj46pO4N1q@xg3KqXoteWjWkvYRX5Dk8hCiL/KqdVpZyS3Tl6deDDYjW5t1/@ydgDAl@Bfv5FHLfEMQItcT05G2BNJmVC@mwBLuTOPKA1mlZiWMUGfdiFhiGg7XkUavjzYhU16FQRhCLptLDElTgjU6D4YAKMVBuWnPaCbrJOiqRJjgIoghRnqdxqhnV0ZtX9a/R28Iibw@wyuDCVJOSUhvQqUnWASphILwRzcqOjzB6qj8@Y7e11Ry1CwENJwBAOWobJVEJJLuiJre5Dx2MtdwqLcSJCPXkqmfRm7iS5JvVWrh2x59xxtO6Yq4j0KcJsh7BZbnaJtIcLfFzsG1F8IkwTphidYgMPofpKzz6bR4k4P2zjfDtsLx6hwyqaBWey/qbij3eX5z5uircYWqo2Gn9KEe7o8rXvv2@1oePt1SuIhMnqVZtWjDYuGe0FP2qgImTyqbQ@hYj7JO4RenSBcthuF2inj89KokYP4JUDmfoUchlCeqIbvD1ycF2a9DLQkZSpzqf8RcoXOOfWgo7y8ukrdNnEDwwQpWInHdih2IIbDFaEjyjWopdqo1tgHlcieDpin13l@SQR9QlGMQ7SuMPuva32Ip2/3GdIcx8SaBV8nfYDkOQrLNZqzwnKEilgiseQwu/R0tp0vX6vvrYvUA4gcG367N3gETxIU9gZvL@9cw3/6J/ac5SBg6ZkzdCMCk@ENi0NMBdAS@kPHVZXUfobTJnj4SElpxEoEPw6hX@2ZA10jt7L@dTGKvPuAouYktw820zMjUZVAobi30h@ORVZ1CXFFQA4jDHUP8wDBHQSI@zxUGDo9GYhzgshKscIKh7mcVrCS/IxC3xIYr4jUWWBnV2tRC6uxLc6jHQsEBAs4ssEiIDMEl8kgAIbXSwuWomX8f0JSoBArHifKQ5DIUclTEN/5JiAlDcvZwYrSisvrJzkYPq4s2uGPvr8TV@/zWlfc9GvQB8fw1Y6H/36Khf6Gmp2eztcNVQT6GHqrYY@AilMHWF/Vfi6/zPIJVBzIFcS7oGmZISkDOn7hXkNQcsEvS3zoycO0MRxpGQMBY8O49J5UhWV@tXmgLWQi/vD7uwiSUcG6An/1b1VMRsKExl5kbwYk6M9G3dZISSJNYFbPXYLNV3ypkDDCXmcgH6rdFq3J943T050JVhcLZSj0ciZ7uZyOWTiKz2UQPltoSlp4GbDpbO9m@EwO7n7@/T9VZbWfsw0PfTcgtKgHRgSmBRexp32Oc4GcYCiWDoNBB65tw7q@je9nh7QgieUOHgwbFySfcW6gjagge/08r7JAfYnwQb7T@wg9u@fwp99dzYLmhKKOoaC2kC9i9uEOj0D8uCLHvp@@SdVBAwXZuXNBPuWeXj0CXcQjBOjwSJnUBPNQpL9E2@c4dC1xAfMTfY0QRaVSIWTE71CjovgCSMSBV2MhsBhlnBuB8PgfMrDIjqvIzi1MamoHeVlj5EGdadfmU9SidYPCdhWoMtb2M0t9Pa1RKKfMKXr/RpgmQ8B7bVKj@xJqkN0ihaGrV7O4OAJMHqRt2J1n1ARk2xikmaPl0aixqOb@dEdjFPQdZNkARUZQMNLPVlR3Cdu4mKe7yENcwxD4kQ3v61V437/65bGr1sWb2e93nqrIgVV8MB@1orIcWVftyDSGQDNQDn9gJ4YXfmPNEzrk0ggFAs4GPq0vO5ghTZWMIznncOf71LFYlE8m2xtiWLxGB4w0c9xUZTxxfGxKGMWFfz9zeH27u4@r7ll8xO8PFYv78UxwOD7ZTvX0zL8hG@HGOAG2z1pkc@yh8@s/Wftw4OjfS/bKh5fZrN9eOJ7lrJF@QMvYMoe04/WD36hTCaTfdb59Oyb@3383SpfJp9dtZ5NLpP9feQyIEPxZuZWZ2k7cB/NTK@MDd4FtLfkR6r0bA9zusqqQqVHGNnTn2B1KYiNjpfdkG89jsOlNXaj42jvnTEmQgEVXoVwRFV5A0PkR/YCzfEwOh0HHfBgv6GEruQHyvX5bEUZ7seuVsA/VdkgBKTMeusAaDzhWEAnuWGMH0gPxp4zRgv4Lcm83D3DsOHvYNaW/Jv9Qd6XsHmREps5sWmJzUSC/uDdCZsX5rPsAG/k4GL@rQrB0QK6GQpvQIIe6Q8UuRght2E8owBIhKTCoanw@GZ0hcZnpf1h@KQMX/f6xhO6DJJNJHTIhFU2Pj0b38OwfIIS9wnjCYUz5jH3BwsKbanFUGPaiYo/vigC2R47AgQtj5ggBReaxJM@qMxnfln1Ro61QbGZBBjJWn99QvMeX8Be9IxiOvMRXQqDRin4kd/i3rjPwbuENn7h9gME6ECF1ckchY0kN5J41oERlEEvqZuCYjz1/knmY1@HhTPDikHz/yk0JqBPT3TCPRvTOzrHpI9M/8TAP17RmkpwWYq255MZQ6syuhnOBpOhPPMiEuHI@a3d80zCESVADIcjqAvLM4wMBZj54M6hMGR9WDj0eCG6LnadZ4JMvIrTwczwyZFGhOwPKZjbv0bmtpkdICaKHZgHCCnfla9nD4YeknymMrj27ekV5lqgbM1iMONzM7LnYV6dCMZuz0c6Q5DJ5TyYz9CVjcnU7o9sS2ycuc2pvajCtgWSz6yTMaGH4@SMkMDJJ5uO655CmHskh4Qo4neFPIcwenu4kMHmPLY4GjQYNKRqKsgEDTgJQuxElHR@DY1VhI4BV3/GIOgoLy3e/mmkXGJp5UVPIwkp6AL8Q9NsaeoYqgV97vgTJ2Ewqv7MVLwgK93gRjuig19YyTG9t2qbajryfFDAcont4@7Ud8Z2aHOaDA2DE5M8y@4L3hdxPlNiD/ZGkjf95F/mg/wBiBXIkT@EEtzITBduj2U240kq9eTCk8HxG/o@gsJzxvfFz9rIqvKsnMLBR5SU73w84MUyskMNmPbAhBlRJc9/gNAb2n3Ab3FnL5AVLzZS3z3Nmq0fLsaXm6mL8a8Xv5iEiVyS1S6bFhvyMFutWHKuwM6YtUI/lVeaJ/gmenExDhe4GJNbF5/eSxIAItlU64fs5a9ZQOhiwzQ3sxcbTJDQkCEm2YfbyyL47BKaG2EsshvGE3PTVIOf@i5vCthb6S@OIb8w@S9goZRKMtODnjPtASiKAaL7CFCxy77azu1s53dAE@o78/TUucH9Nu3dXDlzECU8VGdh67n4JcQNIULczz17H17OoZ@D/hiTQtOIejKhhVxC5TSndgyfraBOhnkCygOVU0gCDHEx/TI2Hj6iwm8JYDlVljJasOugxn0p3D89d4Tt2B6ua9HoEOZI9DJgHxEyoaYRsmS8lRxqqumSpGCzjChdOzDICASGN7uh7RZjd5yWwpqZSe6jEI1RM0PM7Rudo0tTNDRDn0lhKvlU5I@@e/nf/7v288Zs42g7@2EKf2cbP2/svdrgR3iAXy/Ur9uNo40DLLZ3v7HIgg4Mjy//@/9A/aO/Axz8sjiAf452Fay9xcZR@pCq/LpxtAcP@e1taPf//td/QR@escaGmW2etS1BiO0ripTsMfEufBdV7CWrpclgWcnjwoIw2MMQdHP4gY5R8@1XOTLTbUivilt0/xn0Zr4/itziyTFrRq5CbMlQ/hQgGXGFQ2wgzSCVC0VPaL4bym0DmTdAU/zzeWbPAw3gn9Kdw2/Sd9147qHL0DNWi2AAU9wi6PP8cJT7LuG7dxQSyqdkX4mQqNrJtfbVi31gh3euMxt0wl4SarqOOvadc5VBPsw43RvQqcbe0P1xmr0Flhzlt19le2jcz5Ifd3ZCkNKTReYXEARlNhJQDMnp1BJTGAF3BH/hGXOUgEB/4p9JqewcIGVPnA7bsMIZnqBIo1mu1OsWHw9jdzKBKJ2if0GAxzwkMq2GFnl@MYaatXpBJLb8glyOdF4TsXlHzrEy6UiavWEpgy0IMNQHtA6q/mSK0z4FIVGtKUDgIhm7223b8lvKeJJQgeeW8eTaGU4OE@QbBr3BG8lAQpf0ZzFzJZT0AC0I6TQtdAhr5MxsUNEPE/QG9fGghRneXcBnraQb0@rik7Uny0qtvnt4gmdaDzR9x03fwYiilBC04/NMkAtnLPRivLYcoqly6rTxSC22YWjNUymwphn6gxh4PCzVHoYlyO5QBCRQLeiO9CrTh80iXRh45M7hmD02LXIeMGMjCH60VAngrOpZBmUnbDfDjcECceaOnQJ6KPPNcRgBcaiStgzGJAAtfVaxwxIM9aE2cRhNRSjsiCW3pTHshyRwYCylABIMHI83tcAH2@Ddwwct4WgJfRJoeEmYyFK9AilbVFANR4GSanHjqJmxnarVEX6ynp7MBYTLI71I5PLbL3Z2916@@hZjxp/I3saDwUoZ1AIm1zbAIIk6BUo2vj88TCQT/AoTei03idDjwOIBHLp13ZmEFT8@PcznJLBcgmDdUWIqri7NlQQygDh1MrgjgI6SmiZSqe8KLezY5UXX/BX@S1iqNjMcmprt4eAXm0mvjcM7DoigNEcjZ@RO8XgcF2abMrtgXn3YQviLXtZxe3UH76lCX1dme2jo1HUxKGHq3vSvde7IsLVfNGHCAMFn00WBNKjXDkeKkk6tYYWyqDQ4VLXoi0MFr7XcA3TKxS0BZT4GDtMMJgN6@dvS0xRnRxI2IczzgBGreISouY7q7EzcOXZF5awcRUxmQht4PtyM7tkKwh3shwC@UjvBzEdad5tAXZgSfdlrtSZZbNAn3VcucDksB1yBTI@x0h1M66VRRa3VJDfMUg@RJU@8OPAT2gVVYRwRrxiY@dzjpFRxraoXSBC1EEprkr@IWf55jk6yACd9kHGeIi8nCpqP6NuB51E@b9lYwpQepVQIBtLjU4k4gGi3ySW4I7kCjig9ViiNFY8235NKLpN4tygPsK@pOrElBz1pKqCocc4s4tMC@189K1miXIF/Tj6ULRSUj4v/wH77CbNW45uX@OYLonqihoAIKs1w5HOLPlM/Y4gSMEvO4vQlAYK4@JJhA@uR5I0UrFRPJO15UrdCc/sy4ApkV1sK4co6KicJZk0hG8gTqbyT6UzmWpQKfYGNV8srzZYsrKYFm7gentgaTZ4ErfqQmJRrgNiOgkgrEAG3PwkYnj3QSfK2pe6iGLt6Es/TIZZlhQrE9pMskD3Msysp8xBbbEu22C7gOD7EF8S3D/IG32IWZo5HeOPpl/FGen3mSP9bMEflz@GOF5I7XhRw7WHuGHemDq1IFNFJSe3cGI65WtAe3O4O@gO0D/W0n9iJnKUBoAWPLiezKR4kn8O@rVhORCr@w1Z0P0Inoe3dPeMLO78jO79TwDWXHsvO/9TOp3/jzu/Kzu8WcK@JGXkp2snw19@ux4FImAq/iB1eFHe5mPmlPd2TPd0r4G4aM8x/eE/Tv1NPX8qevixgxgQ@cOAUrg9zM0sixUapWg3cLTIqA3EKswLGc6WJuhfeK22J3vDGuz5EaV18Mf6vJP6vcDWipzqS1dZilH1dntVTDpZnyZKv0MMgK@4J91eGeun9lRtWoI/IDYoXaTJsTaWiAgK5xR@D06ZMID8Gq6@/@ayLM6/tlFuJM8NqCjRrhHkzmOIs@VJhlYD1CTPyDC1ppWb9dOt/MRlG9k8yCg2Qx6G9w3uG5E6iq2A4VvxadkbrDsJuSJ0jxCqSnITsTEZ7@@zyZPWqRoktIvtivJLAR22cLhkzUDmaBxCZjIA2GVlfaVXomqvUC34DfedC8V2WPf4iLv1Wcum3BVGXisEqUtnS4Cd5MdDTtnd3H9oDuFYG/@AEzFlQ/oFZ9f@Cw4Vl949iD6nTfut43oaWLMrQ83RzGYFlRLhM8QbKTAt4Zcz4Cv0P3vvJp7YNLdsyKCueYZTelhtou7CvOl2n178e/PjTaOxOfp56s5vbu/nil3zCMFRy/pTJWQuV9400Uyzna05ME5GkzWkta3MAAg3zSbaahA0hyXw@abYKhe1LU@D8HHE@Jj4fCACQiDr2hnhPErlZ@NnDaSjZgyEa2@vR0b83w5hzIFlqaI@uuraYFwT6X6fzlkBvMPm2A4QEEpEdJtWB1XNimibdCyOvnEjqkAtJS/@pd3XaH1XZPicSCYkS/KzSgQAaW/yivoWmRSaXS7EJzMdfBt2wpYRtMn5NmVoP1QLJp9s7l2YByPSBviDDX9vDGZ8Ipn4xfU8YZ@ZHEuDWWeJFDneRnBkKXNCQPqAN0O@YKZkjOOXi/mrraui71o4PoxWAvwwVDtFK@7EFU98P3QFgMBXcY9cdnuL4qhYsSQ1LvAo6E2RCxLDmN/aw54@CylY8YKfKEO@E@0g5ZJHaoYGJEEISo@evdEEw9TU260pLsV8fDxsA4ytyV1gCpeOLlZYKLHEJraGhnD60aUTr8fB6M04nHtOJgDlbPhKUIzrgN@39hvi@VofRv7WnAzRssbUtD21knAzMzz45/M/kZIpNVCQn1/YuzCsfMs0wcwm5@D6tQjm1/BL0XvkSG6B1BzuA1@iqLuBu1qfsho8jvQbKD0znEIcyWGTvE9iOfPZWTJ3fk0JdMolIS/kxbtqFuRtZe4o@xqlXkcFWdMDptYfkUi8uWV4JPr/CccacY7AHTG12J9sQ57MBLOKLwKeZhBtyGNOlLEpCxMA4N390AneuLXElf8j8OhJTbfFA2lCe/mszSDS@onMKWIvdMbbESzxzJ4bwIYIAhzMgb8atiNiY/zMrts3V3YVS2E9vWbCMdDk0qPHddW90BHKP9jMor55gD9HX8SVCDC7DLLAMQS210nUY9wb5aZmz8Uiq3cbcP@02pVppt1F@aLeT3AoLE5oQpN17Ubzq3kzTU/t6ZNvjv2c7npfGK7gnM8PoAFkPDkSyclZOYqiV/ykzWcA4pDfTQubpFyRy4BsjkQhHmZYaDdEo1avvmoK@GTQmHXc4dKR4IGWk2rSLd4SWB52ZEptYylO/RjamFTLoUkpR8rwG4cI9xMFtt9H9v91Oec6wp43ORvAE/71pvj0VTUo42Kw0KB9iI6YowshgACSpp4j4wdNyrdT8@K4CVBwNj4wD9QcKHVG9g9lgNnSODrL8l995swWKAouJA1qgfJell1A3y5UPrtzuAv50B7eCPh0m1NF/YeqAuDW4dfahsk5bQrDnurMAwSzUR6ASWpYRVBX0yiDI1co1URB2F49sQBBUygNOKg8DQwa9hUi@SGYGHun1KTPcsrz5REqjSf6ZwRaTlkjebSVjtv7wQDTeFIGWr09rx8VTzPj1rlLHNJarxuKq3wamQQmWrmVIhr9yeJo7DgkV9GUmJdbox3Cp70k0Dr/7GH63ohv1yusq5nNcjTmT9FB8yhXy9@FPt@hTFfuFLqGgb/fLGKxA5eS0@PpBLFCpW9r36CtamGO/rmiqdva6hikoMXXmqhbdcR80jX4bW44hr/qMTbfxog5vLXqrlo9r5Qdo3h9yZ6KNYmM4PdZqqlQ7P1u9OEgX4XwYyobhI3refHfeNMI1/cUKJgytU5aYa0uVNrWkT8rcXAX/uNioiMopZTzVPpGvy9AZKeiWWFi8qIAKSmun44HoYqlEhSjGFKJxzXS1auxyZF@B/nwzc/YxDrTw6X4y35@5E/mAUw1z/BY41jX16b7r9M39C@PTfYLbPkwAQyeOPt3zYnUxTvJVNLOURFSfzEt4@0ibRoQY5Uq9@r5SVvRoaJ9DJYFo1ZL66tOrM5h2MG5Ooxjln7Fk9pmYEUotbcL0hSjPEJIEginDYPgZ/a76U/SqTdMkh7f7Vy5ufrALdwc3XmE393zfp4tEZKk5Bmnpi2Mk6XqMnKA6jN5lf2J3f7POUV8Qdv3BDoFYC1rp1RATV8B/w9@9gxeGHNErdzZzR2lKa62Gl2uFvuNkCn32AcDkWl0bP8ZUjfbkS8i9RLK1eEtNM0rtfFIt8SbfAKm/WK/XPjQiq@ESX9rTqXt3Pvl9WFPk1LjBk6QgrWIC6SZgXRt0xYVBqxhdYDfz5yXX0orFFOKhlKUuDC6nMzvqEoSJmd2miwiDX181mYloZfdu/C9JNtw9fleahelUx0p/HKGC3j1ApxDnrCSURvM/nLtOoe1/SaLpLPg7UW31mkcp2x9c8wIBpln5vhkVWpD8dC@1Tnl88WUEX95@9a4FAiG1sII9JL4@2vHq2wMrfG8wHK4SfH0Vb74sL0uJckVNTf2br5KX65VG7fR9RZSrr6tN8b54el6JiM1TPBu6dfggWzY1dfp4IQTQj06otIaTmgLRwdAKioPjcywKdsPTcLQZ9XyDpiV6DoeDDGZJj8saukXVz/czdsdObEuqiUAvL8SleIqChmrJX5NovaIv4Tp3eDvooYQrD4R@TZpR0zsUk249STTMcLAEedvidat4j@WyQXgobWg8SiH6BpRFwPlLc3kRul639nZcbUmKyFEhSDTXZsQ8H@6cB4rdcue2lzsHBPuq7kkE0a6VgUZTAO9hzDqu94cjBm0@jhhohX801TCqJUQ5M6LLL59QkAvCKi6RDbdoFoRPw2TQ2z@cBUVSrYRxpibt0ooCy9qj68k6U1Q/Rw0OUudPUYm3liaw@dgULrnD5SHLr@xfctq/Ap3eov83/V0k9izeeuiSi/jje2vFqf5DgMwHhjt2KYxsCtWzcuVd5QyvpBH/qHz8UKuX0STciG4N8uL3yBD6nthkQvV0m7NuYFUVuBhlo5i56p4okGOuxdDtwKzAkSBjGe3E8@CokcFz8As8yJuXQyfF6iCelgkyZyTD1FiCwWwiltd5OmbmDiG4nWV@oEyaD01ero7XUyzVXaxZNx9TF/PTr9v29or667b/Iq4@WWbZWCTtVYgR/1msEKL99VIfIjTArBqghyf50vCZv@8Ain@/ESTr11eOnzI6/VGD@OqvQfT/72q6ZuWduMrDNSvvxlSerdvyXlzldVt@uZJxfVPnMvdaImqx@wx2lna3v1akP2lFUnbPhxal@EFDu99fw/ZnDhtZXj9/4MgQ@dfI/Zkjx7bgzx86tIb@NXJ/5siRPfrrJDg0REYGkQykUfxQdY9iF26H3SvQrkkAwh8fEiHRohlBIbBmOqk1yGSu2xiqk1@mEH6prveljMZOO2j1lmZroTzWJWMVLlf1Ouy98b54Kt7WytWTOA@OJQJ5zh82pbdJ0ffJFlhy8SN538QZzaZtNi2vTVURCwSdBP0xx/D@2EmGfkktVfySbMOy/RhXa/aX9euZa/g@S8/du6mL8ece3rCkQrxH9kzjQN@OUizjpcqntfM6DGy98RkTvev@PgPrTlbSkU2cX8L9t@ygr9bAKCf5iytP6mjPZCnEDD5vJeMdtDVTJ8XS9IauHaBGbzHJPb9eMv2G20h/TRvp9drY/Jo2NtdrI/s1bWSzcY2sWJbKlePz1yIrGm9qH@LL0BfvGi@IwtudOlPHGa9awsJrGNT5fXg91nL@p1kBIzuEPxr@7IhUetR@L5ejn0A68e@x0BchbXB4@Hh0BmOVQnmt4aEL0P7A8fmc/SJujJgqfEzxm9JzhS3@rHaWJgN8yBDPd9j7nq26Sd7zMEmgtMp77s20o5@nUGpaHCP@EmSmTS1FTj24g@FtSmEHWg7xwTgvle@BQl@FyiTKd4PE8y07pm7BgMc2Evjhfk0jvpfrUjuhhUmJJ8SdF@P4zSS@77GLZeDt3FpyAL5sJRGj5KViSCJELJgNHVA6ncYqn5LMqMnCp3uQCQkUPN6vxiPGAzgW11iv56WSq32Zl/k@aN5cSdClcY6FFwk58YEvu06bK@LH/IkgczSH2EOeI9HlEfpFEoUHj9zmoVTO4doiaemRPCvJycdpgaxpiTksQfhv3IK/tst47ERYb4DjHcO1a8roMmFj5Tyi5X6oDlc3YuZSLIxwtTiJDU9@geDx1F6xOWp8vRSMSBwhtQA@Y186TnyI86lqHFs/cuofWR96SrEIJjaenvtTO5m8X7E28Byj@v7lCUgVC4huxsUp6rgdrUKNkCBtx5N0AT1zdUkspMUrpcyV03dCWecC6KvnltyJJ0iVM3fsfAEJ@e@jRIzhwPAE9v1N7CUbiaaU8dE2iRVpEisogMg/46bshITq1/J0mF1XocM6YlHUK8WyaDTr4uT8rCSqZ40mvqid0IfT6lkl5lRnET8s@vanCN5S1L4MUj@uvfKGAfGG@K@0CpM2rwgux156uhGz@2P/CJc/MseI9qForTjKongZT1g1QoXHaRBfsQWwLwNFfHD5IKAB58T4N@CCeGo8zBePagOaRjB2hXeDSb1wM3HmoIN4SXPdNapV2OFlCffq32in1ASE2J1ytdgRsxjFScsr7HnqSozPGDgmId0HHyNbSDVT3ZJhrJx3VCC/wu4XuDnJBSHq4RQanoj@VjyGVbdYalbK4m2l@aZWbvifIs68GKcbjdJdDn3TQnDNSHB@8srp34yjMaYU@jburgmZY2djw1ozlKspPuQ10xm6QKMljOj29@TKaL1S8fS0eHxakaSJBuzNnY7UYzHnb3tiz66jPWA1VkXc@sVgt58mI9lfXiWj6OkQIt2iwYi8C@nWsl6kCBLaNB6LPOd4cUDaj9eWTQWJcbRyGaZDkNrGNDCzqGEgF4h0R6TzekD6Uy3qmK7TkWnT@bWF6ZHGzh1NNdtPSmv8TwjkXjO8MiejK3NxwZU5iq1kp34Kid4PYiwTRzu5XRkP/lhcOJNYpjoKB/mLiTtc9IcuPMMDUDzbdW6z45vh0MAtvzvo9cKDoD8ffbONN2I6nWtXADb/Hw)

NetSurf supports `+` selector combinator, but doesn't support `:before`/`:after`, so previous answers display nothing in NetSurf.

NetSurf applies rules inside `@media x`, so it is polyglotted with litehtml. It is separated from litehtml with `:,c` selector, which
selects `c` in litehtml, but nothing in NetSurf (and all modern browsers).

I use `white` instead of `#fff` to not deal with Flaks.

```css
/* <c>419</c> */
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}  /* undo head+body{display:none} and hide all the text using color instead */
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 421. [SSL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/SSL), 18330 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"$avdxddxdxz$x${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2");print(349) #\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print      (not inspect.isfunction (lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0); '''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+    =x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +     +8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ? R`"12"`"420"
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ? R _`*` *
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.  0; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Exith,8,3"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   Ford: Eni^ x._,_  \;ncepp headCa 
 ; ;:在ｕ
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({b9ca543d-02a8-42d8-adbf-093bb36e1a81}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PYdSD4UdHw/IibYFaRTBJPvskkM7OysrqyVY9UVlZ3WySLBYIgiU4QYAFgJlmZrOjWOLSSJXtsWfLItuyW5fGsvPbEeCdm1nKMvBNhT8R@mXDMJ/@Aku3YDdsh/QPtOfcCIJhJZlXL9oZjQQK4z3PvPffcc8@5L3Q1b/jTnybwIkeONRtYjk98w/NJzzXPDFckd2ZkVzO9gprjOAy15w4mI8P2vSqXIAohlmYPJtrAIH3T8g03SzzDIF3Dcs7BXyVke2JPPKPXAFuOENs4J4e2bvYAAvGdU8M2Xxou@OUJuWtYl6NLn@jOaKTZPY@MXdP2qW@BkCMNLP2Jfkq0rue7mu6bjg1exaUkSku2MiEPHdczAJKjG57nIKzKUhBFJu9qkN7YMqZXICsK@cA03B6huRi7BsuLopL3T@7du@qaI58XHJvcwxxe8cqTvYnvHPpX4RfI3sCwNaKKFVG96lkEPPmGVZbL8lWvElSV4Zv61XTKZK/fN22DPISyXvWsEN3zBE93zbHPQVWSe6YL1awF1Ul0zYZqw0rdIsZo7M@IwAhBs6yokj2ieWTiTTSLhrMno67hhgE9X3N90x6Qc9MfEn9oelE8Gtoba7oh9AzLHJm@0SOWCZGcfgAFQNs9cmrMzh0X6j6A6djWDCIautk3MUqYDwCIV8ofGgzOSJsB4dg@UAnRiAfZsIwQWppLQPi7RncyIM7EH098AnnrmZ7WtQBod0Z6Rl@bWH6WdMEPqoS6nw8NO6BqACcCiBOH5eqjCc2asSB@rdcjMhA05OPUICZgjWarSnI5cCeOC1iDUGGOAmCUwFkZjSnUMNRZ36mSgiyD/0HkgrnVLM8JMrOcNfS0odHSOkO4R64zcLURYKNnUJy@f3hEPN1xwQY3hmUN6yYwuuaT7W2SPHh0N0kaUbWIbpeLqqhOLqAKEqEnOdOsCVBIvCYcqB83is1hlSU3klWSBLSoMsnnSR7ab5moBUCSIlfAAIxAzSlwF4laJnkF2luB5CBwToXGXQQfaBAkLxeSWUy872oD0zIY6AGCLmHbgTgqPOU8yUGzyBVzLPTAsfosqE5zUSK5MimWSKlASvCskIoK2cA089BiCnAX4QaIFcgjAFJzkGNZZcAWjQKIGAlxn/S1kWnNghRoEjopKKQEUKEwCkBXywAF3rkc3jm4ywht@YrD9odQFUPtDMALlnmKvMyI2BnWrwQvaWtLonwTGTNL3hti8oBXwGihTEqQfBEwkocsANrVMiRfkFlBvKFhWUG0oYfRaG5LMtyQ8xLgogxVIwNOZURqCW6wA@tUgUeqwBBV4HEq8CVVBXMOk4BwWFdFqOdiniUz1LxTSIilo/ZoBQDfBzAKYhz5oYJIAghQawRQDTSQByrJIZUUcgTyD3kpFQlQQFkh5TwplwjgsyITqB8F8oUkpAArViA/CgIDOlCAEBTIkwLYVgCokisQLoZsJYf@EDcHcQE1Sh7i5MEMFacU8YZ4QB0KJKlAmqpaWVAo5E0tQHkLOUq6ahFqtwR@gDcV8qoCSSG9qmXwx7hlwGEZKbuUzDJEaIgHqBVsC0CLgIwC5IfChbBgVksB8WrWeKh1kfGzmN0@Ri1iGykiGiGqjMWDdx6xCVmRAQy2Bsi@ChSQo00J3vkoeUsBIE0Eb/RMyr0t7EGUCEOlLCXIj7Sxv0CbUqQ5Gs/8YeSmMjcHuKoJnNEYaPos8oRWmI08F67FHLqqlBEvAMl5dPWA7ToTz1oAiQx5lSZlnJnWwq1M3XqG1uub3vDVIq95mkjX0HzbPF2kUihkY0jVYh5F9FhyKuXiYX1TgL5sMETToixqCcOMnaiClrKsKDR7XaM/sQeGUCnH8kd9/InrQ6@zSLPCnF1zMIAefAFHydJi0l504VygObRyOejcQ0fELqbpmtC33yb6EGSTyLPC4FcqCxg5FWHMtC52@QLIatBFVLBT65tT0r2t0y5lkcEcxZM@NMdh4OrawLHKpYlMy8UYbVDMvSzLEXvGqy1@5Jh2KkmSaW7OQUfE5M94Nw693QfYhWGnjKQLna5DRYoF@0zZYbeZBqQtSwDQJVsoKXUNXcPuGTsrg3a2IRzTFwkkAkKk4ZyhcEt7zKVkPNqrdl2UZUEE6hmuSzAsCMBelva/3qTrGS8mKGQt8tWHDt2Afr@vmVaUAdqPaD6VDuCd9CC92XK2@64zop3NCPtXy3HGa2QZ6M3PEdB959xYZH3R2WvjsQUiFbgbTKKDzJxrVCqnInw8VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KRBHTNXSK@6DoEDsHQstyFqtEbdzOIZQ7MVkrB40F5BAP49gTy6qCEGToJNeQesaZhC5MHluWwzAPoYQGclYAoquB2I05p7mIIN1WRSr7nYQ16zmj5aKx/vUwKvrQRKnJOtdmUHt96FqNqTYC5YCgBA4tl4yAYlgNYk2AFoHFOiQ9x076EZRzFyRcKHRUEipFI058c2SAjuRAFKzxPM009u40Z90ZkDLFVl6kShHLyRVEidxVRDGHfMyBNRaQBXsTHbGGaZs2pSAQlzxUAFxglcyN813SamlwuyDsjQM9UEQDBnyCWYupEx5r7YFYrlOIKMAatgcaiicSE7U0oPyB0wdiOzeh7MCwIOoCtk6RgCiInKaiLnIU5UhAo1OLmEQfjwm4Q6cE5HlPLoN86nxkkpfgaQ1Bv9Anrjsj0zHUhDmCUL7u9PtAvS@N8RBAkFGP6DMdmidUMqUeb2hrY67nUDajj5cLu7BtGhDGRr1l/@jnycAA5INM20etEQl/UYzxmBaEIkSzmbxra4AvLIg@nlHkcIlFjL7jiOjecwyPkozjnkYMABPzjAFtINDa@guWNEL5HWjVpnpHD/hP0MgQPibIrSwMJhXQwruGDQ1IB9qEpg@ViDW7R/qgkMcEWVRFNF03xn5ALQ5laqYdUwke30OVgLoKATDRG3Kbu2T7Cu1A0Ih@YhItqkiY9XGgqWjIcQOtX6DiR6SVMv5iza4lDyHOrqTOP8cwSzl4zq/Jw5g2DNSPKKuY@MhQkEea@hA5oo88h0rd0ObcyfXig1s8eXdEhH6UNuZGAebDiVLkhPlYD0OA27oOSBxbCKux5IBBlxzeAFrzRisgO1EmrV7cVZQ0EVjjm4COHNtZARWQGcHFIMs@tC4oMT5B3qFZETHS5uIt1RGy7cVAFHZn0JOOx44LLYOxnhkdbKBVFqOuQEdPRT1GWiR3ljtY6DiS2O372BdChLGlAS1gE8OWCvqVBvwCWBnToYHzOSzFWIZpq6ewgvyd0w6AERP0qLZtoIqmuTMGBIoHnTQkNCOm6wIzPMOugvVEYZciUjqFnkHr9ZC/Ijpou7@auIgUvT/pmtOrirqOjuJHHnemuaSPOroLogc0olSy7yXTNepOY8a8eMkZ@xKNyp48BKSBRKjyVB/Ufugq7gGjeTKz9RS/1MT4LOEnfr/Mp8GAEZmkRt4DheFq7lCJQKIZnUK7prYaGUAnLgjwFNCN5gQ9JBE9NBekDWiEoGtWKr2uRi6Be7hEmO4zhSRUTBQxH6Vl2L0orQARmJd4eUWWhOfq1CDE@jYsAQanJaedxBIC3xITNCIPDpIU9LDoQGU@5kelG@Y4senAHkkxgSRNLiIRGDqAFM2MCSKIqZt@JxBabt8OxZeNeh2IDWQqYJu9dFyvDQc9ReDUEFikMkmQiOg7T3xsG6k0lBcDz1luQHgCSq03yIU/dKHFUfucg0CAVs5GSg4RG9TzI/N00rta0TY6YiAeWx2ITqbu8zUORADWGuo3YTW5hFXQfZOIVSRejE9BXyNe6ooVygfBXMNDIbgeZCVWwynMQUCrK1HEogZuC4Len@lWIBIwEzR2xo26kP3TYKwrYkTZQCYIG@21lsqAYHNgcMjR3sn9etAWmafUNe3qkoPl6JpFnTcxOB/GfXB453jv@Oc7K2BYZrd61UEy8@UidrWTqTCwJ1JeVKubcRgLwHc7N8PGiMtheC7wJoIzjYlKMx06l2mIzsfHn7@KEpCEEB00BTDjfUWkYWFA6OK6mje80gmTQSYDSUZRwrBEOCQhzMiAWUd/LczP0eTlS6y8q5kaB@6YM2uiMQCho3Roh/FE9LwigIVe3T7rEWlckEVNGycyFqZ4yDA/76LsfDUzVKCOkcy7j@8dHNcp2GB0TaBBJM8HWUpzeyLQvDUBRXxVGGB/YNJJRlxkHKVqmteVCNb1JQQv6pasgQ8AUOMRHSJYo7Bo3hDyvn@1bNRV0CMKoHYK4apcGZeH9M@a0Vg@sIvTUfFd1YtSj0VnFTmt7LEi3@VuSy8UjFK@Eu@29EWavThQOm8A/UAoN7rgdeoJ6CIupMhArA6y/@TBtYx7VIgEVUAIc@ZZRKRpeRaH2otgkqQn7YOe5liG@AHleDzh05KUDKcORN2jKmgs/MHU9FNymr2VNISF1Pf2DtW7YeBg4JqOZ1ClATVy7JncPs4F6h7QiO1YzsAhWxCHSYdhgiA2rS3m3sCxr9WQho5Y1AROJwL/xeEbbQx9jfmSqo80VlxpZROTmu2dA5dWijlEEsUQBSXR8OJH2pkG6FqU@8nhFw@gE1EKshyZZXoBCmJxKLrQpMdcqQMRICExyM/KAkbzj9dae@ghxCYAsdABo4si7i28VzpSjilKK8OvzNJ7zjWMf@TMrpAWuDDSAkMMZYePjh4cPjp4uPdhy1cLhSV7Xq4UAXGQXhdkIXHI8IatdYs1TSwWgktA23CxeQEXmICCEk4oTTwXGLeIQUSWgTVUw2ZuU@85Qzvppa8W5hx9hY9snZHQQ2x8LGgQERTtnoXKiMtmtrE/R/oZ@v7Yq0oStPLhpCuC0ip9pDuWNpBoPOgYLEtSUHU5fIyjG96qGJAZb2awGGyIC0SHGR1H1KyRA8oLnR9H1kBSDDwdu7LMwRB0YZxEN9y0GFEwLY3UAw0BdGUpKhtlwNQGuA3eYT3xjLTfUdQyo2tFVvMSHwZbav4QdqNvgOqUgt4KUJG@YiWt263bZAZcGiFdBZIg4hYd5PAI9gUWAUGSjp2inh8ih3ILHDVFXkFx9GKCY7rApaSCnC8pxYIEahmoaSCzCjjyJow0Xx8KviMAPMHp03GDGBX2PV2z@@JWYAgzC3LfLShqrvms1bLbIKC3btO84dR0c9ZuKu10jVyPshWET9eAepeKh7QbOgDtUiOQJn2TNfysp11nZz2Ntq4ekfzROOhzhDF5uAeC1EsH@HXPiLc9jCDFPaWtpbASBn4lrRgQsjAqhw/ElAQNCnpaID0J8yWA0IviIVAO8K1YBLIYzYgEppk/BP6RI6l9akpfl3DRORdwjeWs4NCwOJ4By6OBkGkLOcxQ6EETHDMImJUkqEAo8aB/kmWBDiScuMDSx1BNbEBrHzoCUOc8HIr0sQvGOZsJGxvGJhlYccBzT/gi0YSXNwkXYWgA/PoPf9AP4ERim0juaEhxgIUrkl0QUSRPkQVAXz4jPh1p6BmoxuP6iKe2iYqIyFFfAbqu5GZH9N0NwkNar//wT15/8p3XX//k9Sffev3Jr77@9I9ef/ofNoRXqGM2tjOtliBmm23CJ69l/taBemvvzq07ZZpDkCch8//3L/zq3/7aLy3nfUW6P/r4az/6@Bf/5pc@@esffPyjj7/04x9@/cc//MqPf/jVt0rX/r9@2dH/@ydOkOQ5Do3EEwzSg@SGQ@hF74PU1ty6dX5BNjY2IPrGxg7UxMbODsmQHXgK8NyAfnMHfLPw3CFN8N0gbTJvc6DBemTFaJ9Ix89FQ9OHHeCWupHKpUXo8i4up5dkOGxORWjnp7y@xbfndHaJ9gU448IyvY@V9oQukcG8vwfdN7MtMr8u6abUasqtdusi1epl0q25lFXaoGV3THx4KTXdVERRADfkLSlJvCjPpShvUxoSAon60F3kjE7YsRU7qEszgr9nTqEnAlYJhBQfk6eshU7u4NDqF43xcObGA0TjVSCf4tjzYiEIrpdB/hfnLy9Z/LgotKQjhxIjCwdiIQ57oaQxnjG@yLGctqSldUhhj3Um9EeOr0nvi6BuiLGOJrmRlAQB@hDqwyDRYj80PR1UC802nIkXH6NbOXSIqYPryXAC7Ht/aI45Qx86QOm7AJNEsySIZJzwEdi0URitp4twY7NGloFTDNAb0zU6JlQ@bb10FEOhSZ9pltmLxrILxfELMUqtRuMQGRMyB7bjGgIgAmJwdEESXe/GNcLZ3EM6UnSNVwa@tAtAvmsafpbcsxyNYtSxgRZi1IhzIYv4oM9ClGOjx1k2EfogWoisBlyjJ21xdG7TcYfALqE0OGWjRnU0Cjwkxxv3RH8KUbkUdlBxT6YNgZB2Tnqqqhb1Qr8a@iEtALKHUDWoxdmgEoZeggKe6aBqD9gwSqjTPnp894CNNdDOCbsjHHfqjJzeBOSwQM84NuxBlhwAFZm2MwJWaofxX55ax47jM60YLOtGMpiSaY4mlkbHSK4OY9wYT3e6jkWHTm6Kugg/cT3N0tigTei79/5DkI2fnjypi9VYIEk7G92YNo7brU6W4fMwPlNHZynD6RSPESa/WeCxmwtXVCJzCTzK6DHCNZMgKwZaNLVGjkHAC0WeY9i16kYUTqHhmIy0SOhCUan7md/vLznnqPOpgLzEWjjnqTNbR7mkDrndRaACC4SLKpfCxAEVaZhobeXacCUaji3nAGJdeJSph0ZXWgo4dL/kW6G@i6WWKP0EHCyasB8aVjgBd2yMHJxkgl7SwtkMEO1RkGWLIQ3oK8Y4l0DZNM5QQZegQcSrghY0sbHAQnOJDdpsuqYt4UQRtymRYIS4RhsOaN1sZs9jLNQBzZgOPmw32Iwwah4uU3okNna92QEQ241auDhtXTBMKZmMglGoNG8QgxaTToJfK2q0pMGjQ9IcjVLjPAmE7qkqC61p6aB9mZQ8ioY@4Vut6S1Z/RBkElx2uHlbGhg1uh5oDb5qoU@SMuygL@doKDa8qw@Bu5DMdBmVUD8Tu@9YPYHNJQGtEaaFYAUFE/rRcshg1athuuFKSLoUlUVFrhpbRHkN7pUqbVwPEFt2GQFC8YFcnmbPLknzNEvORG9smT6ISChPDINVRfbVBZp0PktzXW3mccF6kDrZO373/abcZhC4kYbzQ2VWi9NwnS9oba4zwZXZYMJVLb7p016fztqbWF4QciACnUqA7AMMlkCNRAkFJaKSj3G5KEvfAH0uZVBxaTbKEiM9F/uW5vuGzWiOTdKtRzebTQmSqdPkd4Kh@SqR6fyF2Ydcgh9ksUaenNw9OD4WUaBLJQ9wnqMKzRFERxBG1hU6xGS88FVyq5cktzBOGpVbDpoaqOudID4QdQ2IfmLgbA6ynYHhpsAxjVMUOjjTWSEakUljAYJwbZLuUxxFwFKgbO8wYNWV@X9qn9rOeVTjVaD4DMUkoDt1u4pSZlqc2OYL0YPuhQqaECTQp6CXqG@mKCfbVNLB4rMRTrCCUE0FRChBs0lAZ@I3ITBP2u0amymHsOAHbohdnqdVQZeD15Ww6uvgDIIMhRBEr78iz5qyUGlnNleBoguxgpXcrPwxuAhhGbRnrEx2M0Xb@7WGzPLAZswY937q0eWPy/sZqmSTGXg2MkuDh4uLKNOha5GW1xQtr1iCRoashA5YYEFClpAI1tkHNEv9KecHrRejUYdUmlxESFcR5eTykuKQbKqE4hBMCmGVMQ@1YmBMDxwozYNgjX1cJqCtNVhugW22xfGhor08n4k@TFyXzq7IpMIZH4/HZELTPnXorEhk6siiUkA5MIo9OrWux8QFm/SxFDTKAwurrsudN@r26WNFADo5EEw7Uwc67BxIwCA6atIxfdER6BUpLy@1WEo2WMpJe1owE@HFG0IKlTIN3O92zXVBAQm4hip8rwgGTArpWRXzorIo4tXVOGQJv8Ha0uD9Pz7uAZ6v18IQOgQch4sMHeiisUaE/tpKCaKihT5WVyAbLp5YpkYRQE1vAqlrLhRJsyLDatB0SloQoJsf4QB7ULNAg/gAwfIGcmI5Z/Nj4Xt1IqummGxgjfq6sFdWJ7Gk6GQIqG09igQm7JgGjURZFKsEY8omJGJqM7KrN2cqXEJEKNGyeh9O/Al7gmz7xko0x3jf1AaDkHJB6yqGxFZz31DlrnY66TnC@HQQyaPFFWEXpaejRQJ0@8HkaAeNq4vPCshWR4fvdcEWXZh0Tl9vogrPnnhjoUt17B6z0YYwuiEF12LPdUHMYNtbZFiPNdOij7ekxAA6EEqwNkDC9ZdCDGnmFTRbWneGssbws1NZNM8OHKeuZzJybs1E63i8Pj7qlTR@pbI69lTUGT5WjQBIbI1noGDRAgerPt9Qq9AtmSPNEtRezLiWaa@apr8WNJrho3FwQwLdlXAjkWPHo08szV2YbiDxa4PK14ang27hyNQd6O7HRCmJirpgjuGSsAVIXExLH7Fpf3MVwsLNFEJkWt3YHd3HpZJrqOctWBdboogLQWPkIDrrcKI753ivFQiGoGyy5@q@6@XKXL0FGxIs3dKgZ17L@JcG@XAQ8Q0keW56Bn2sRuzpyoz6urXSfZnYw@G7@HDcmwjYMy3HI0/o8yYEDVzAAnuuJt04Lk3NFuhQdtx8A7cJ5/YXFapZA8cqlgeSBo@1tT5x@8jhg/fb8rKIFynKG3hRKOg4thK813LwU8k9fVMF0e16Lq7rjBlv6ExXMaRg7mJ96UDUx30Lq0t2Ty7TmKLEhvjWJIyrWc61Wfj@GTqJdagNO4nxjArIIMdhhEoZDL7LhOafJbX8zan13o4pXQNbelMhYpV7ahnQLdHntSolqqx8xhiKLL89i@pbE2NirFQdHnc/MoIO4@0Tl4PsbgYj6ziYjxswolAvA53urXKHPS/abmQaGk7evVk4WWZeY5Cnx6j0HoHhCA3XYwzsyXip9pb0KvuYoWY4Dpuo01vKBfp8Vr5SfoOMsyRZewa9b9R1mG6GC53qBVmWA9EjNhOyZLlJB8pFcT8y2XMpYeqySHkRFme/3JhxdRoULfGldGtZirpO9aaBKxXJNm3Dn@HzLblj13Gsz1JTwCRx@6sDeqZAl4zeVGPXxJdgMwRZDC54OCTR7a8bVmC9R6AVAn5Q3b2p0uNTNW9VmwJORo5womjZujoNHDi0tFG3p5FU99xJXweKOzNxkIatGbXWi4LB8IQilsXSonZ6TtewNPaaFvM3xauIuRVtO5gDxTlTNlO6mNdOXOEd4xmU1eyBejA0Rga13iBeaz08zCF4rQ00dfBe5z01DF2aHhj6ugBjE5q1jc@lqdmY7OI7Nig2Pi43QwXBwgWNget6ZD3UXNN5sPfo3fgcexDgcKQNjHuhdhAbEsD1MkxxWhhXDw5UyR1sSjpEC8AGgqV9asy88L0y4sOZDhU1Ga1tdDqODr5FK1u3BPJ6F2YPnaE9NIZs3XFkW0elQEg@BRxQjz0Y4pKn8XhpKXQcD5ZjWXE8IIthDMdx@ivTOMAtkbiTZ2V8ts86eL1xmErzWeNDw1oyHRoT4OOe4ztjQ6C2dUEtHNJgz3U8J5yx/VnHSm7UaAEV4ftnhf9G3WqgOf54TF@dsTXx6INGFeiO1TfJE322xIIuhnPcgfjSGXXFwFEM1l/QSd3Vbbpr@voQtwwzijQGTlcfmm/KdHBMgRQObjDrW@luiBmTCHfRGRR6QK87E5Fe6nH/J/g6XFfpwTgJ6wwiww39@6qxKLopVxhrp7rHxv3QRKo49BlrXWzrbpVufq6@mJj@AmhsTU40kMkG2tGwLu/BUoK1kghdG79gh8ESg7VUSoVXFFQFQwYBQVmX7PIqrVgTy@XYYyVv0B39tB@y57WYDJan0CEuMzb4CO5LpLO0rmalZG0PJwPvOm9jY849kFbwsV4jp8tTY@Ou0C1odvBah0HVknDfGrw7IH5MjBsnBgo3zgzQcIolaI4Jrw68oFYma4eHLHPssScR@mvnjYLlNqBmXp3cYriZrdYTg4rpGX02jo@mN8lkoF@D8DqA/lzQcdoXh4GRT7NOm/Ek2xkAvxYssggchl2nK61cDrO6@qPuTfjwkTHQcG3sA9PHVYQrqIK2j1XLaN4I@wsTzTO/MIGSrSM23IrP5szc@CJKtK2A91AbmPr9pYqIMhkgOFiCyF5L5I9O1@vifGh6uPwmMtww5oIkx4gYqa4DIvSKkFcHn6NTCBYNiO1sWxl61QCxM57hBqAZNd00Nmz6dAAxeK/TotYtdroxE@eT0XjiBa/VeaALfOIDrCPGzrxzE4ALL4BrkqFm@asHYWOjiSBIBf3dwrg6ySr5omk5A/LFskxA7vKJiXLuCsK5Az3vEa4ece0VlEjTfsu5O9T5BSa3eS@gbg1cp26b/s0DGL6PK0nCNxaGdQrOOcgDD/Ap7n5WCMLJaow8iHVy0a7SN3TRQGFPnImrG2iMjoqIS@QBdGM/XAhr4uZ6POriPK7Z6I4FzQgM1sqmoTv2xBfciX0j9y/eyP2reFxQrLpJ6gsHD5@m47VOlwu/SZAMD5RamNbObl8hJtMGWWo9v1wOHYr9d9lBN8d01eob4uzhaTw6Zct3nVUqyNEMOopVzHwyumvoOJf1xjQeOQ8d24HeZQyMb3RssG3ZS6sMVkfEaA9w4zHgoffGZJ5QsGs6FSY9aGOjC/VoLUxv07cwwHc1X1vTtdBhL6qSRaY30oRpdQ33IzqeFTOv0xqXM3TfmFI1YD1hsLYm@LrOpFccalpqC0uTC97YcWz2pNxThpfy8GYuAaydPt5@9lbEtd9LqvdKVWq5qI/P2NIFo8fODVhXVtfoOhZ73rAgxjbZRLXmmoYnPcBt6NStmCcCSFPejbyidCOvWGgxIJmeaR6dOV6tFSxAKtPPsC5lqLm6g5M2geGGJSOxveNvYMfRcnI2m90FxE@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@JPZau0ICJYSc5OZWSwk3TU5flVaIHEyOf7ZIinydWuMHu0qa94/NmKIo6/D8ROtDvZLC2spaDrBqitNyzt5iNtQIlBEhchJ8oCrBfONi5ZIwAtYt4QNHzANHMHbXrsy4CUDkXFzZ4M8Ne6bZAkpLgcvYiaSMLxqxuZposcgZnvq8ctoqWm9NUjo1hmg@cWNe@/t3DkOPY@Ye2N599JQcaR5oPCsgGjGIC8niIwHHa/Awr3UDF4c9Fzg16ycG49V0XyVPNLfn2LNprKngLC52dfT8yigO2mggwzKn5irerbPxmaPVK0HCNNgKeWe2JOfFz8cIIrz@8q8qiizT00/wrcjMeoWASQpN2gyPzop7nRxGpK9jvyyCQ3qlVvXAmOKKATZKuUo5Xcm/izfw9lJ6Pbu8ya98g1/@hvSu@aEjyYmycgPAwg1@pCBG3g8c63zoiPuaa9yAjpuyXrkh65UYvwkOZKazV4F5vdCKK8GD10p6OzF8Nz8eOl0zvyQiL@@jXDvc7msuXX8wcILF88y@OqnzSdiQH2ovjXgTPl3wAWM4wSXjKybSuiCIGfbAZOevkTuOf0BtN2gL0TbR1XPN5vjuZHyFleBR9Ve40weglDnnHrmDG38W8uEK5RLXFq12XydMkWiECY8avH@yFyb6@ImkxlJc5OLDoyVn3BrnP34Sc3ON6XSdtiVM1ykvK30WqT46yS8lu914dvaGfRXQswGri95ru1zGd957cr11oqYw9EdW6POeZhshnJ7j071S0TjcdLwYHP1gSAkg5GMrFnRBL2KaAMOTOh08u6TTWUclJ8aHdGAZ@kriG1MU65mAHxwRZEzzQz/4TAeNsrYBOKcR134yHpr2NLCMFu641o2kPvLCEu@RJ5ZzTkKFJ9Z8gh4Lomhnhn3zpiahkru5Q87Fe90lPLFvAASvdSi6s6b3vmO47qowx7p0L7S8r6ZXhHjvSRhgle@@5eAgac@cjFZ506iZzCovd6lhX41krvLAI@xPh45rr/IMK6ZavWOsBb1xg99oBtraKo9uv7/K@cBzVjk/nFi@iUJa6PnImUDrCcnqwA2lt8Z2o9USq@LCiifyekM3HXcBTjFyJh6Id6aVvhpU@Mj0lxyv4Ju64ZHAhi3azlW47znk8@Yin/FCvFyLpffuLXyWx4knOFNId8ctjOt2So1nuTeS70tzQC2rCc82R1d8F6ctHbqOzWzp@LxPeNbSCmj3NctMr58IVd8wE4psjvmTs9yqVgYM/14co@/PppHkfGTRnbuBbV@FAgx0PR18McKjqy@VXGxQgC0ZWbPsbcGyv3Aw0vT4kOPSkQvhtJG3YOIxzcJ98ujO3skHRw8C@@e1UTdMITwlXb3LVm1FazSuDKPQc@SlJ/gUvKEGfRcdQRFwE/WVGbQP9h4chex4CCI5oBKPeosNNEV8l6R6rqeNKpEE@TDcp3QX2h6aF5zo/sxwhElUKNbfrVLz1@4euHpU1M2hYwc8XauNR4b/ZOL202s3sqqrlZ0ntArYnmXokuKnwnvZ4HQitsef7az2xPDo/lTKBk6QXv5aUnybOJ6dnNrEs0M36ZZwCHt5STaCbdjgwYcbu4ON53jEoGlPDNw5zr6h4tc3IZl6XSlUyA5@nqhKFJmmiR9vq7CT3MLEmmTzIthUXa0qc7JRJ3yVJ8G29uhgZna4MADGY1GhUEQ4VcimDz6b4ZZsQr@WQS4JHeQTdDx9EmyiFD@cohZsWoc8bV4cHR4dPDnZO3n6pCm358Gm9rAUtg2phUdn3Mr1eCh8gDdQrthR4/QwBQuSo59IwMFBLywXwa8DLRetvlS0RaH4HYyzeWHbkkT39UvCHPIn8Cw16ovSDTgx2GGJaQUFRzpU2RZ7elIA1BEDzdM0odKqRF6V8FjzPChW4H/1Y1rUF7/EVsVvsWHCwenQIEwNHKcXpOgZ5M1XmOK9vcMHT48PSJjBBdWcmz1/WK8U2OHhwblhPO7yt@gBGMkgShLqql5P3ksCYpJiklTpSQz04G48YywZ0QOe4RDE3iKpTQofMJiMKkX6Hx9L86SIOwLSEDYZZioJyQLNU0LBU9ZOgEjI3ePD9w@OCeb/4C51RhQhCHKC28P/4vs99umL8HCm8Ct07ihQHqC2PMfsVfFsBt0gibyiBge89AgeTMaOLyDGlH5GglIeHbmIfZcuTQ/M4eIHSoSnLCwOgsCaoxwgHpN9ooIesBB9GyP6xA/H0QPggN7P6fmFV472S9Pjs9g399ihmxFoSnrhMfs4swfKDu3wTM/E4x2wHvrOxL3SSHCvNT3JUiR7@IE@/AygRr/iApmd2D47CSw4HSgBFCpGvCpLNmlm2Tdf@FjA5PYGNJKuATon8WwT5Bu/Sj4CCsZZtSo7/kMQGslrUULQVWoSUKOJBWTa1wjPUifC@ACPdGu50utf@SVpUCNg9sH81cA8le@A7WuBrQ/mrzPzMwkJVEpe@9RHlJd4hvCoz6AELCNc3/zpT/GbnXxqU1FOO@5ZJlmQa/BQagVSILc2W4Kw2ZTru5saINJ/MW1Bc5a28mfG3WG/dziQWjwPQlBekrYuLi6S97aOzGcFUhR6plp8MZ3Nc8Xci@k8p5RfnI6VYlN8MW3z5Xr2tN1qtsnR0YevOq/S/PRs9gL6nRQQ2P5jXsnziWqFXOwUc4nTCn7mC0p4Sl7Cddon@Kfml72YWUNztw90m@RJotXCD2zyJR7YXrINf8opnsPFeEazITbEnfarV@mmpvnTGTFNc@z1enA7Q5JS1fQTAk3tNjQiFkEiLfqmSISrMJr2yXTPGAwmB9rMnNzzd8WSWBbVGGPafvjFD4Kr9sHTp4Q8JU@fvjxew8bamUxKEJrUPA0dH4Bckp2SakcrJPBDXX/xg4159uKos/0Xn4wkYwNfj/H11flDND9RCrc2Nm7duZPPZ1VVZeajLx79/N7eXv5utnDULOzkBXlj@8//bGNDVbdVaaPteUo72Tw9/ZBX5Twv/sX3kp2joy94XiP33z9@1VDwUYLHGSmRCl45ooARn2W4FVIokLe9Ei8TClyJGf11EqH7xQZRGjul//nNxy8SfqKhSh@48PYTLxLFcoIZwQC2XGg7SzQS2xisOE/MpHq9DsbS//yPEL/xHsBBn9k2PBqFEFZxlmgIdRrlMtEogkFRVUj3//n441gOgZ8BK6nTFhleu8AQm00@X1L5nTZcW/Ta5vBUHEGWpDCc7Q99wyFK@bZyGy0mWOBlwwsHL1oJ/FTh410iPjvOQJ@QEd9vbEh3twW4xLGkKGpLUW4D@xVubdXrAvQrtNnmcoXbeGJhmvaGA8d3iHH7g6Ur8cE/ybUSTO2Df8rrmOybuuE6WS5R3Nh9frfRgPLmGrmtRoZeQSOj7a1U5h1nF3jNyXDimg5@87D2AL/e0eDlsspns9nd4w5EIdMpolCYTsUOgiDs08kJdokdwlywOQeOjBbhaiAnaJPIncUKrYtw5HmyCW2k/Xx9uMQBXn/5n//y23/5Tfr7Nr3/Kx4pZPfMvrQFgc6guTTg2q1W9UaDb7j8RQvtDaAxuVqulqXOvJXaajbaxyDWvnuZLOSS5Ik1y3aw2ZBWutWk8Rs02UaQPNobiYVzg7k04m6BBwtMHeAdYIokwnLGyhVhjZAr4bhEuP5FaJ412gIOodWFplIstAUWq7kLlcOrpQrfaSeEzRlwIrXdUAvqY7LbYBcZbnrEwdzk1GJYkCC/jUXZFj4LWyPulGiE0RqLMJ81XJCnCpdoNqW2QfuKRpjR3Y3qRrlarKpSp7H@qi1i4EWDGoZx5CXOEtFVIwEdhvhMRJQZc3sWr4moWkhIwGQp7hvCQV0B05hOg/@ai1ZXrqjwtcCkdnhSA/pQc4I66PCyAq1ttxMJ7ztwbcCP/uGKrPjcoC6BMw1y/dogVWVLzUmFW8UDFbveq5crNBsZyhmFdiMjIocUxCthOOhLiN7tdl/qXZBMNK2r6ZriaxNtqs00vzvpTru@PtHxU7bkCMW7ToAGN@cUnLITYkUUErmCspm4jWXLqRX8KizoJuVyrqLmSkquVMyVZLVcyJUruVI@VyoBwFxJzVUqeVXNFUu5YjlXLOaKFfzyLoQpQpgcQigVcpUcl3jV3CDHjL9NSSa8Wpk3Xk9FytHwogYHb0FwpgkQnED/z3KJf4aroagK2YLOUYYHSITUSFT6gxLua@bEy3IkAcLeRfvVVvPVFonXlhDkGV5iZ7edEebzJphrteC/3YiMNXoxExS1Pc9ktp81QAZ61mhmAOSzAKQoEApU7DRIe5t6RakFyQX@220Qo4TMdnO77uzTW6RNUWgDyO2lbO7uUrrahZiNTWjy6UxmUxA2mgCnGfRGEBipLygPQGqnQFa5uPgZb5LMO8mis7u9DWxlvj1vzJvb8/n2Nvy36XMevMF1vn3tT1@La02YhX8bWVKrKTVaUitgS22wi1IDXUSpBYYGvCFcM6eW29gRoqAjtv9l/sXs4hm5YJbbIuSaS2yRrQSetJNLbHGJ568//d/wbr3@9A9RaCXwM6pc4oIQLiFtVQh1o68KSG4PbfKQXTaY8Q6t6IIOjYfoaLOHjaqwJD0XSVWg@nBKKRfTIvb0Haffwa2MInkOQSHYwcCA9hKyWcKr5SLfySgzlSS2@WKJctafu3Ylk8l/9VytlJJM3ca9eM89z3sYy@UinxC4psqKoFw22AGq7ITrn1t1/aufW3dxicsKQRylCMMLlwAySkgSqIlcorE9woVh@HUIAT/zdVb/UHi6J@w7o7HmU30cB@tAKqgfHtQrlQbqScbmEW06W3e34KnA/2ADCkFafQja6tf1EcjgrX6uoLZQLX1XA/UceJrQfYG/By/xR050/B2/wB85eYm/Yx9/5GEXfycv8LfXxd/JCH93XuDv4Uv8PR3gr/W5XE6p8ZvaWW/ag//05eZ084LiKqNUlPnmlKc4q0Hf1mh9zndnVeNMs1K8uqPy6Rqr4ly@kgbF8nNsEKUafPwAF@4Zul/T6pVat66ysKyjTNlO5C@a3uKrcmwHZ1VN4xBGrlJwXEEjpgcPcMjkKorjJn/yjU8@SdbrSSFJjwDPg5vQxUBdGgisEDOfpvmh3wGqESADz0vWdpOfa9LhqkKl3UTPNnhwiTrZVDYV2ZJ1WekqXTCYRHaJPJSHSk@hmpxsEHkmz4g8cpQemAz4yWAy5T6RB0S2ZRuCgS@Y/I7so6kPrwH8@gDIhZ@Ja1G6iqwTSMhCsZV@mkfpYEz5skPeHTqenx23uCZJEv65ASq5qIiyWDTbeFB7k3/@vCVttdVKmYhI9mKn@byVbPMtHo/xVCt50p0ZG63nPMgpMs/QjS4k4Xmg59cSUqslBdWg5mm1zuedzsGju52OhB1mixiNzG4GOoDd3Tp0CMFrJ9Go7bSqtD8J@5SEtL3TauQENBcz0Fuo4EbuG5ZhZ6XMZ7wWgOHd2KAIaD8/fw5qUeoclaPzM3idh4YPWvDoMLWJekvnH7RiVmqAC8NK0gcrICwZINe2C4oEWUiD8Af98p/rb/7L@j98StIk1WynUxfz7RS90vhLpy/mF/Pg2UinUoEltQ0/dAA7RrmYN9BIA12AqZlKt9PzOXODZyq9zQA2IJntBo27CAfdTiJKkibLHql/2jckHVytZI0857e3Xf2yVaPcIC9XSIJ/XiPaYu6h1ZrKwDm64RnDgk02tUs6UJuu6fgBr81uU2n/@ffoOdI7aRqokK/VlC3CLGperdXyoa1UrtXKoWUzlapcvxryjlIEbSqfT6drNbDshGBlsELcJnmVIXXSgmf79m2WSFm9vAxh5vLFjIxzPrVamFIBkjU8TWc8HCTTw8f0DGbgFoUEQaZAgmHrlEwPcUfenuSr/O3bqeAznTt76du31Yp8eRm5jMfgpCw5dTo90@100D13ecl3eDpfUCmAXS5fXipyJaMkSdpxU4/wW4uQVkpQyC21QZOtAM9W86U0fk6b5qCwvV3MNxrFPLgUyxARCsU4NjBzPlnjExe0GEq5xPgYX0NnkoAGDf2odzFP0Jok@UI6BTwwDXLmPIE/F9kl67UKhXQtL8uJiznPAiuVCgudJvliqpypBL/6Rpo0QIhiP5QEc5n8VmlrF2Rq/HnTVRdy1NqFUVfm9Qujil/wmNf04Et2uCvUuH07VwHUlOUEuTvBvenZFhew4zp0TCiPwaPFJZMZcus2h1tm3WS1tktrVikXSCJZY45CEtg6KQOOJXWroJQRJ5zZx73eIFRwCu10N8gGp9I3PrgK64o30BG04Tjvo3@uBxfpkS4Z4EUGqI0Sk1j0IhZh/vSp61Egh12Bb2SlcfGKXIzoYoPwuUKOUWmSPJjoJg6EHT3Y2z84yarbAkmo9/b2s@qTp3cSCloLCzv1zqH9@GDv7uOnEOHowcHek4N3D98/eHoE7h45X1xRLxH2FVGfETOtsJ@TD7iP3JeaYWjGxDA655PJ@QvykWl2TKhaawJlcwYu8YwOFGmsLYpXg1s3Pe2jjzR3TC/y@rtffv3dX3j9u994/btffv273/7Jp9/@Mtzfh/sb7P2NP6oU8PmTT3/191//zu@C43@F@0/h/sFPPv2Nj9lN7T@E@7/F3H4Y3LFw7OYA1td@8uk3v/eTT7/@m3D/dnD/5vX7V36w@v72l9bfGO@bv39zmG/8R7j/gMEKw37jd5gbvq@F/x0W7uu/@frX/xP7/3nwQ@Pvvv71H@IjsPzyb/75f3v9yX9R1fKf//vXX/rm6y998vpLX339pX@tvv6Nf6/I8cfvv/72H//1n/zBX//Jv6H/79PnH7zN//Vv/vJf/e9/9X/81Z8E9w/g/k9g@sFf/Rdorn/3x9/F/zf/@O/@9Lv4/19/7@/@@Ft/97V/Rw2/xQz/8Nt/xJ4/@uTLP/rSr/3ok0/XPL984/PTt3D/9J/B5e3z@TZw3qZcn9Xl058pP/8YbCxSARoAyv3F17/xFSDeXyfk9Ze/jyvR4V7z/76q0DDfZ7b/HxjU62VGHxlMcH/r9Ze/gSj6XwBF8I/w9dXIsuTDLF9dWACt31kR6Rd/8umvfY/aEka1QSehsJcuq@XMFig0W5VK0FMH81MQ5SvL0CIAQUpfRe6z5PdV5Fuvv/vx6@/969ff/a3X3/0a9s9CvpLdywrKGyb3IGDhLcJhwOLbhMOAH0L6nQwdsxMyH4Jt48NCOWfbdu3DDz/kOpcSbnnYvSQfwo98GF6EeeGWiMAr9EN33CNBwL35/HkbZ4RjbpLCgEsqewdeuNYHUhLUW5kdSVGZl3EpbbJYpAYOuXKuFcu61O9vVeFH4FGtbl1khZ0WCHk06pwzwiIpAdQNiShaNreV0yCglGfhSNXelfOZ0pamgeaaQbgZKuZshcJXIUemmSDJaTBrjO4QaLpFjVPCBv6n1HvKTenkMvxLhJRJjhCb/WscyVCJiF743Z3QSA1BvHBimhq5AiSTWUwrUGmQMEFsi7nQ6Xaabh60DzpXl5mCtg0GHAsHrzsg7NfrGYxYZ1kEKytMo0xoVjKZOpQbY7M42U4ZQUzvUCgQs05RUJ@yiBmE1wjRkeHQieYmU67fhQTr07vokEHgFOzz5/VGuT5tILhXDDuZaeYOzRMCq2emjVdgr1OYEI9L3H0FWSnXM5lGGRPEQrLqQQUbK6lAC0fLjnO9rA7gjQuudnYJucUrZZ7NqGwgwlhofGYWoTEgRjl@zisq/5zPqzIPgVuZraBs9B8a6b1Fsb9B0w2SZGXHlDcoMNJ5vvU8CEhDQmqCIIoigRsXN@yQXbLDMaxlMjQz8MoESKR0QukiciAUU1yG1jpDG8AHZ/phQqKq@RroGzWCTq7O4XeM6IoZmduc4mqoCxLIxnLwcb45p0GYvJzjLi61YLXUpkbm4FTkMARNs771mS/MLGJtc3OTSzT4HP@Yzg9nJIm4p1W65g3aM9WcqoQvVnh0NugCQIbFh7jSOstRcw2LSV5//L1EXi4luM0k/RAqYQmRWxl27@5ukVuAVvqOuU3p0jIhk3PyToKhcTuT4VVItOGAbYuiMEOhcc9Ioo5/cE9QciMJcqS5ppflspRRZuEl1hPoTR4/fhzklzo8q3MZaIdqTkE7zg1OJhOIbvRwHj6bFcWsmM0Gb5G@qYMYGETqG7zFTUQ9iWt4SqmMX0C09SHihXv16hXQBoe4qB7iUCg1krqaL1NPQslgiou@tFGWYzvCLWsWri1V8xWOjU8QpZgnJEUpAq40wUWUKaDxNMdWYjHyCq9UUi2DEo0hocbEFARjYIoKciq2WpXu/SCF0pIVcha34qgjG/vGBQLRMlGWv1S5kA499x@T/ccPHx48Ohm324Qz6Bc3jc7YdXTD81Lot/foLiNftVJMJ5pNLPtJVUXOyR1UZSTjzOHd48MnVcIwFlRdipajRufWA7xUFC4xHn@wnXBx/N01ePzAjMM/wWd1gYqUWgGunk40uIRuoBoGdIp/uGvk2Bgg@T70BnecKUnJWZ7PKkVUktM4VQzZ@XlnQvAAObZrHbgDrugTobyY88aFEJuBQocGOVY5ZhAUaiC5Sjk0lJhBKRUxwGP2JaYc13hycAKQTx4TRZVFcux0TchU40MyFQkBHnDsjAwnK8xpbORIJ@bIwRBW3TLsgT/cxK9b8i2ZjyFosyln8afmcvBU8sWsUii1NzasCwHhtCjJXOB6xTlYLwTEyTtwEe4djrwDTnAJc8I5Y8MmweD@4eMaI17cD0lSkPsnvssrBeALaQ7nLAJ43Dh@1QDp0M6WJ/@4xMYXv@iTRuPg0V3h8B4ORUyHJFzsKJg9cShSwulNXIP6Dgjpme@buFRb7Jne2NJm0IgBX1sNQIiPk7CJ@XzeB5iH94jaUKmVxe3hc65Tly6Y51ONI8Cg@1zidjj6wpVuV6v1V0q@BHmrVl/lVJUDB24LZA2zvwHURheubEnsx9v1vCJnlGA2xCZpnudrHmQqlytLW1xC4Xl45XI5jjYgwlUNjtDlTK/kel0IeHxeoauZODxVW5vW1egKwk5vLcLmZBYWfcCDDHyXyKFfifkFtrBbgKLg@l76mcVawFHk27dzOAaVy8tR2QlFDZlDlW7m8jmsJHAD13YiXwqm0aB87QRnGT7p1cGcaGGBWWNWEjxBG/K/XFnmEs0ENG2u2W7W/7//tZtce/ov9w9oaTbr3BQ4ZPwOnDEMfZOlH8c9dB4v/o8fj@LWG/@jx87Dx87IgT/0hA@RgdcW/1ptyXrzP@CcyDxrICBzvjEFcoJfXi6A9R@@/fHf//p//vt/@1URr8AWOfzDt7/F3H/7V/H5rW///bd@4e@/9W@py6/8/W//m8DrH37798hdaOOzlxr0nxx@X/zTP8LPjX/yHfziOFjj/0//Q@D1ybcWjvg98u9c@3@L/M2v/J9/@52v/vUPPv7bb/3gb3/rj3/08dfVsvKjj3/pb3/rB3/9p18jYP/xD7/yo4@/9je/9MmPPv5FCBf///iHXw29vhQ5ghlcrv/BHeBy/2Iu5HQ40U/nrreD8/oadJ15U6nk2wfALJqkvR0e5deA0Nte8JVx4B51Hqta8k3mxjc8w@qLuHq7zm@PGzlZ5beD84Ab5H3DRmYcxG/06j1Hp9/2rfVEE7@xjJtyWLx8nq85Np7aVY@mg0kqfTGon9PNtjWjPhDxfAjX1iyI3nV6M9HzZyBq6Y7luPUkKKNJkFbfNx2L0guY93qOjZKgXTdAWcEh@J1cLl@F8oljZ7yjFkoCEZqKDOIb3ko524MOxd2BfqyqZjeMnVKp2hN1y9DcnUK1gN56NK2/U5CrA/HDhw/u@/74GCQPw/N38hWIgGcs4WkoO@VqoQBtmOczTZpiGz9ayjpqYWMDOjZD6wnwxll/T1DL7SpNv15PJndyiioo1Zxc5oLCLhBm12whrxR35KofRyM5sEzbcbM8h99WjGoBK3CoNPJyfluCNyjgEi5BALGkQfaMgYHyA605ZVsaI02AEYJqYOyCsbAtdcFogrGyLZlgnDRyirwtTcCoN/IKuOqMSrA2iNmrQ5pYsgxmO4vkkh0qF0FHXbUd25hz1ayWNS9ozVX7/f586yKzsHDahcBsUKdzQct2LyJrTYiFq5JJVjAXnuCi9YFELoIVF1VeLZT5WrO2sJeKfK0953ZHRs/U8Lu4LfnieqwiCFAMagISahFuXnUdx692jb7jGouAOaUYBmQZuh4gz8@j5FoypnhxPbliLND0YoG9CGtdy9FPg5ToB@JWpZUv8HNOD9DhGr05SyhbzYaOLColDqwsrLbEs2dcYuv4/VyjAdR5kS@p@UK@oOaKxUJJBWGxki8WykAcclEuqCqwiHylXCnNoW1K0qsE/cIU2b8I22yVnjGe0qrs5L1mm6RfPTKti3JOYEwmla6BdJF4xSVuHb@vNhrrx7hSIHi/rwqNeq5QAVMOTWqOyiKqKqg5IacISg7/bzCo@H/78Cr8VXxCrJzKneC5JI9A5gVx3yYP8GgF3yEnjkP3Cd0x9DUh9ocaPQNl33U87x8R5o5mnzKvuyY7BDPyuq/hl5i8kekP14R4Oh6Ztoebjf65IByMupBB5OkswB14uJbjrApQIk@P4HF8@O79k@i9utQPo2OlATnsXGmIcXKwt3@fK5I7jx/dvfIqBOAK5MHBvZPIWmK@YdRCBOLnDx48uGoNXvnHT4/7E8fFm7v3@Gl@8YiccHsVl4drOVDkTIEED7SiyISSPdkAFTs0KBzu7Lqdr5DbgbFQXBhlNH7A9o6ZXrT5i20/rHIn4YYyjSCj7xoEv1xj9OhIJj1lLRgFUEoVjhsT2zknJZn0HMvS8EPR/Q1wHGoe6RoGKrUW/c45Jn3uuFbv3OwZGyBqQhoVBT/Ki5ng7gOQ0UQfYgKgVODZnD38hDPO6XetiUEm@Pn0NY7wQic0uuZgCPLEuRMG4LqaRuD@rBfEN@KXf7ODz9Kgbtd8rOvBuQS39xhHKyoJnt/n@fuar9Vco/SMNFBQGmbL2RzvF/gBzv1ant9rbk1AN9rYyJeJ2pL3Zbo0aqbVFanWrROleNnYyTu7qDmhKr7VMRLlQb3qFYrKDvbBdTmzm3C8@0a5xvOanQWWma16OApxj34h@8A2n5Gp2MHB1FbNxmEMuvF2XyOUxKp/853v//jPvoVSHrnruLqG65FRbyVUCw3UV5GOmqiVcqFcyanlbLlSzheUYqGQVdSsUiqXKpA3WSkrxXKhomTL@QqIZ/kK@BYqpUD5laQtsmfhYFeWKbjSVhXA2zp@mHabDsCIwwaXYAtEyMuUliYJLbJPCG9AHJ7s2QPDAhg4bubTzYxbZh26baLIJFciAFkjOkncu7cv37vH83fQgsvm9mWe76GlUJbl0h2eN6jPfhklUN5hccp42hrvM4ss34EanDAAeMA4zw/RclDE6RCeN9Gyv3fvHqbTR4uK8SHYKfNhFiu0lCCYjRbQximAFxE0CLbH0snTjB6gBZNEn3vMZx/8eP7dMDvoc8yCMQD3w5Lu7fH8IbPs7aHPPi12gWX082jZoxfPu2CB5sXzAzAMXGjYPN8FIzYyntfBpM80cMOPAePZ1Lav8fyMoQcRxPNTGlrTT3m@E7pjMu8HuSkgdqvUorBS71JLBX88r4aZxmC5yJLj@XxkyUPZ7t9/Xxv6PWPArpnL3jqU9P79nGZOJwf3uu@@2x0Muu5s7@DdY/Ta378PAs1s4nYH3SBitwOXA7H276va6Wh29YJSH3Y6Vc1a6fX5Tiev2Ve8OrOOgTmEWC8gZ8E1wIRGnX3w2r/f2dVWLfihADvIX0bw7uJ1ZwTvO1qXeYUX9aLvabfL16AZgLLSSnGoX@GaHWyep8Cv7exI012nhvZpnch0rfSsWZTbNepBRqAgybU5@vdT@NRwbDp9MWtO63K7Pq2XgmW3/RTfmqoFk89ujHaUSqG6oe0oaj4zreI@bKefJElB2SEp5fbWS5J6lN5RQU3a4Fs7OwLfVNo7xdIzZGxVfOyoSrmal1WSZtZcqQpx5KRMCD7SzVJ7p1SoLiKXShlNUqulEoh@gB8fBIgujgZ3SCp1bmin6TRmnQ4nQnlowcmMFtqs9VPT7LTOMklm6dq0rtTYga5EvgItlerhKeETHU@TIAzoAABOQU/CxWIpXqmUeciDJKXSwIzm8zlDzkVeLs8vLryLi9Y8YpUSmBYDuh984eT05ORD4FYgkcyyVAhtBEOhR@xj3LXA@u79ffHwcWjDA8DFeygcO664jzxuyYdJyaHTCahK4n3o1kFNDt0gju86lnhA11aDhB16hKdwiMEhneLJ/SU4T4bOOUsZInk1FOI03AGP56ObPaLVG2DSeiRFc0W09DkVKDqNRr1THxmjsT@DIoaxPk/o4eELMIceyzv9XgN@zZpGv@i7zijw6NTlOXR608RUEMgeyHcTNwsQO3UiKM9HTu@5mtFrPTwg/U79DoKpdeDdBUXfcF3H5UFP5Wv9Hbs@sT2tbxwZLm7rP3y8CYIOnoqR6hMjvUlaBxh6H/WqudBwib3I46PJKKUJjW562QmnDyIHRFPqC2HxL3D4HHLO8/Nav05SzyDoC7C7myTVE@@kd/I1wNgd0kmDk/y8/7xPVFLM16galEJY0AQpphADWrre@DzIZwz0KalWITdBlZ8CVEwMAENtUB8tPTbnNb1ukZRApmmKo3xtUG9i9Et8bAsgXAhC87KNo/8foG7wYgKdZwOae22W0OrepEs/mUHkrqLKxdoU3JRSvjaE@taeTWtufTxxjZoF1mC@gNASazXALaAQwLy8TL3@ysfpbaFQZ241CuoSZZaO2KlPazYedgiUUs/VwSPTzMvZQhnEmUIpCyKEWswqxWwum88KJXQF@SFbyIIjqGEgGKWsFE8In5WnsqhkFUPJpuTnZu95OnuakgEPFHnprO8c2JMRQReoMqRWaoe3ls6oW4CinkO0bYESLzCZGpYLcD8kYzM7pJCODc1iEdICyW2lrM0UBto8mYwPmu1q9WA6/gJ4pYQXO8VMSc68TKdrqY103TNe0LmVOyYQiAbIRc5Eiz/eAJoO5lSINxk1odbBpJTUarPZxbKW5GxOzkExzc7lYJtv8O2svFFUoM7mdAxdIYyzxKcRQHLiFm7jDuoJlgF1qFTUGifi6H2C3HEndF4jV1aFilTYKshsLoGB4MYBi0TcklQr3JmRTCWTJTWZXCjV6WQNJ203@MUsGlW16XLaVBJYNkneVgvFHR4EQL7KV1Qegi04LuaSyGHOt8i@Zniai/MtHA5VkDyo6hfc/GK@3eCmIncwMi1TyxLb1PHbU6Z@KnIoyWZJ1xyQvuZjWxa5PSjtYVXknoCeZ1BT8wDPHycsPj3QAqO1A4BVOhflD2cg@7oQf0an5nzxuivUEsF3mNRyCPI57gmeh7CtPsNf6dnDvcf4u7ebwD0QZPdz4FcB9/Kzh08fP318j@55X2xK/SzXLkckutEBxPdaokbH0HEVAyTDZPu3v3ZxrppIG7itm2REQWzQAwN2WSqt4OgaaYOQz7oTI7PdeMbeLdzpB6A5evhxk7TpCmnDRDWdvK@BQLlDklDlmjtqqmqu3VRLIJZA19WUWVBVVWqQi06C7lFtAH1PLyDT25kGHgvweTKbaRkhLPpt0hhkNmV1ljjr8MVKju5h7zQU@ZRsJG9v4Vd9BZI4O91oqFuZ5FE1l0neTebyibNUa7ORUWZJiWxl1Fkf13vhuiEpCeFUY@tWbiv5NFMtD7JVJYNPFZ7VJBE2Erud7G664nGUkkliCcEblb363uB4L5jiIHv7jbI6C44zSDzr8OVSkMXWJqBMzTzbXYrfAFnoGU50Xqk38jNcu7gAPFlLJi6SJJGcJ@fNZJtL7NKDF1R28AJJREcv4KqtYI1ALl8k6QRJB7ZSJeGl0nTNRDBJ/7nkbiKJc@HE814BUdO6oE073Mb@@ecqMJqE7YQOzsTH8VwQpQoFnOlNSM/H3hfVcu7h4WP7rnvP4BKtjcsNB2fxSY1nIHnyyn7vC4SMocaSpFVPTOv5YK5UaTQEZVvFA6tKpApCQF8pCvJlg3GzBvUoquDz@iu/mZ9ul8GuygrYVbWQURsNZQvE0MT49ad/6LszcnHw/t4DksSZ1x//2ffU0o//7PfokvLknM7GqrlSAkKiUSmWEhcX44sLEALnzK@QaCeuLbNrA5okRauUtkSgBamsgaEjJYKtbCmlpKQTnpAINhQUC0IqpUhqeitXltPgcxkcCpRS5TJYwyUR1IkvFvh04uDYLKjK7vYOlGwnl1drG1CtSnSeBol@24ZXSXCJ8sPnl4SARW/0BgNTpSZJCtrRK4FsvxK24Q01/ErYIM/rDVwrqOBRHOEE@xZu6MflLslGRtpKEtC1SaM5r83bGTpJT0c@nm3ZrSvIaG3gttBlpy0bfsaWR3@GQa3UwQNraDO2PvL41FZakno92u/gAglBaCRYq@sYpNAAetmSIJdb4aQ6@wlCK/36K7@hqsUf/9mvXHYuOx@qqlqpVIqKmvjpT7cn9sQzeo2fQsSj8Pg1ICLd7CGxnjinhu2J0ZgD7exMG78/ZNrRWAVhR8CZQazIIOo8l5jYqI@x8OHIBY5REJBJzYFt9OiIBXeGEjWt1g478KyXosG2CCgkWarP0ROW0jWOC3Udpq@5Az1LYZAtPC622U5zF9w76AXyGQGdr8a9swAFDiOQyBy941kTd0y306ZoPKWdJbchCqTwDh4mtwGh0yTotwXgxNBXX4vKsuxRrFGZm@DJxng0HYgj3DsQJTje2pqRseZ6Bg1p2iAriBiE5pN69JqQdhvStliEDnVN0dKzAFnCcsci2aDGce@AfEmxYILYScxtCFADnvIOIADKkAoAm22yTXJpcmFmMrXFuXdzPO8Et5Fq4cFsHEZDaD1AUxS5huHACdRH/IYn0kVQw8D3Yo4hEAaDrXergwKK0akNBXoTyGH61qAA1vkQa4gWjdy@vchVvW720oSWCOGfmmMcr6X1YK/OKwALNflbwFJBpMpksLLfWSY7wHiGZheoTmBHCdZiUQmP1jnHwf@tiRYp8kpVUY8aFiCoL9YqdEAZREa0szrUyXadKGopTaLM65B3nWaKHtsTDU@0prdE9cPQcw45/Gki/BwPMKuT@Bh4QLd3DetydBkh3COghE3oEZX@UGPMIPgUN8gsEB2Z3qEfxo5iQVFMi4bumy6ownRZXXieXSqnpDHa4vw/mg@6ZU7NE9y4Vkjji8bC0ATeGp6vFqSzQcVX3YEK9caOTQ9k85E14dZBoAjgUZDAI8c3WLYn9jl@IyuoGxo5niMoJWg6SPmYY3rAHP3wNo2L69O6rqGdhrjJEmMgEn3UI2qFpCih2bhUw47ApWkkmuEuaFCI465ljCBLTwyD7mr3qpI0AMFv0sXZb@mhCXQ1vGdC92N7UvCNc@ncPDWlEzwPWXD6uPmdAgcoICti82Mr3EDZnFg9YjnOKbHMU4NNbaTih9vhZweKWVB@soDZxQ2IraLYq@ayOBCmZFkouEvwKjFjORuLu5Gapa@/c8pGqoM1ekl7MNPF75efaXYMv/S65ILBFG/mcfQsvzpB5SEFdjFiudAy2bFYSTwXK5kWAfe9VJqj9etBFIwp4pTZOMUn@LTojS3Tp0Zu7BpnBAdDOOxjgGnqnSAL2IqhtO/QDoC2PWhZeL6e71ah5jKQE7eX0qHpBQzeJrdITuUwIKSMQVkGAAZWfX0ZOvhBVCyH5/egYkQ6T4R8BVrnqAd@eH5XQH4YP6RuNNPTDhfkTTYCcNjp0LTqhDWL0FKIWbB1ID3Tom@AZxFyuCInGyk@A2AzfJpnoKP4V6MzaucoL6mS65CyBCEEqAYoVFTQkOXgKbGxj1zhcpE7GnBnPMccqR6I/vz8XKRHSU5cUzQ8/PCT59iaJY0HJojDjuQbo3HwaVwTv3YewF2YBPZdN3E8HO9MUaitV27P2Jvj@l49WLCaSva9JHaOZ/hdo8HoDPUryHDfowR1z6TfPtNTwfpZRn9qO3sR0l8V6U8oJ@cIhBAEM83OsnoWgGW7@mm2f96rBR5ntEECcKhFI3TEA17d0DLyQpM57kchHB/5aOTVtU7pmgKAxLMZg0XSrIRhyFloDexjE9e528Y52XNdbZai/mkMjQScmlGxh8yg26c@YIRuhlyw00bNaXPWXoo@jaJDpxatHQJGnsKe60ag7OhZ9J8y/yn4T5n/dJFomGxz2mYiGTrNsThI9bhgPwyJYGZhmDk7pnXhQyGDHE4UBgJDzpbccGGvXqexQ3wzG9RjPSQMoIkxINxISc1nrWarbXvG@VY7Iw2A2HmKCKhxAN1sU5ye9yIzYt86s8aOt@QE3QcVb4J8o5M@DKiB0QqWMaogShgMXyYerTkYBWuamEAQFBggoBwGniga7PkpM12LzjqmnkA4TX6BY5axZpCZNpW@Aq/ADcQlhnqG2DigdgwQukdFgmyCDwlbDvvMX8gdPnAdCBOGFeiXyYBFzkiynQRMXmkqjNfUaCXFciUIYTYB7Siu1q8WJfSHqmhe8YoVcx7Ufzz7G585@31oF6tzTwmWdRg1Lt5UcHU@iBBBc6FYJY16rF4hB9KWZhku9FwHTD4NemtIZksK1QyWDhbBOzd9fZiKVb6eZvVDj07gbb4akcKsXocizuqsWbJ2EaKUITyK5gXRZiEhBPEZAwEY8spoRhBtGo82rdcZ4yDTNdHOY5mc0kxOWRQWevr/tvet62kjy6K/o6fo4GRAtrg5tpPBl1kYcMJajskGnEwO9rBkEJgZQAzCNkzG@9sPcd7jvMp@jfMU59SlW2oJYZNkLnutb/baEwupu7q6urq7qrqqegWSl7IaaE9Vtb3g8FyCdIpxAwmAl@dtFMSgSUJ49q2DXhw/3owmqFWpNoM1h7hA8hCK2MhnncvY1lsa0tqiFQGAjLgEoMs3ABeM6IKXT/u//DWKSanWKP4l2YDXCmAwWoL3DdaBfCYjHRgE/sQW7QMwdxNbLSORp6MC/F@O/0tY6qX6L7/8MhcumQ@/zFmR//0uLy@RstoE1aSPfG4HF2QjsFToJou3LmiDgR1Cc5rQXuFhUfgdLABjKsYa3AihpEhxe9C8QPYFnuLMHviRpKhg5YQlSupjvNBYiXOPUjRTI4Kyd92BnnExTpj7WpZ4ZWUINkYhTqqnFbFJISI9EpyV0JyYJlhKYTSeDsYPIUCneyR54yQiq8VzrwD/AQ6WAglkIvtFimhjPoobUeTqpteiFExyIhCfilRexwYR7IFyPMbjdSvx3BMJ6xuoaCLjVmonphFOty6PSUL1ATlvMk5BLSuRziSoKryDpRXfmWEQPJr4XiEMKKNsqhQxVCjwcqsMXerhzKEr475Dipmdzb/K7X1rUO/G1swatb69tDY7hwkBS5A9Hnk307vuT333@rYnhmLy49W8s/jlZyF2dzDcVWx/w4GL@b3DLAVavRQYCfttjhLlSwS/o9BMTHSdUSbtpKAU@RwN8FRQun5BvgoFlAkjXCo2R4oL0agwOxy19i4Px7AIj1rjy300a8y2Dmdb@a0Uvvgmb2KWHqyZ6rRml0CXe20WbRqvbdBq8L49Ubzy6PAT9jQjZC6YwQ7p4SksHV7gJSzDAQj6xEx3pJDKqDpQVoBhA4j6JbhGtYeaPZW38Emq91ApI2oI@W6AQon/wcMruzzaYfGIdYZ53wEkHneBhEFp12GXfbHNSrsjsEdYCnbtvo4EjjiaY3D6@8ncM4ZMbG9wV6kvaBzD@1IFKq546g87dcEw/uNm0Pmp9Fps53Iv87kXeY1keEkmIpjLvNgJtisgkvqwjW4@u/kdwyi5kwW77cFmjrB20gjQEqeoHL8Hvcy5dcZjxygOh@zf5@H9A8701ulmDKPudMl19OqGKIJq3A2SC7Ra92ba4aT1dMv2AvkCb9SgNPcw@fEv@iWOQNXpyVvBLAOtIKCQjQYztpW4twO8HMK3/PTc4dC9Q4J10OjC9MBKIwf2OGPTFGGUkFgKF9L3RzfeDKc0Wo0RoH2Fd1h2fDKMYfPrwMiQCcMYAigy3GmNjbsRTKC9ztBGVSsThwA0pFFAIQBd6950nAdxMAiJz8RByI6poAxbjUzWnRouzZWRjaot3RavCEyjQtU03GGAm2@qDdGonTQ/FOsVAc/v6rX31XKlLI4/iuabiijV3n0kp1zxpnZartQbAkNAS7WzZr16fN6swYtEsQE1E/TBKJ59FJXv39UrjYao1UX17bvTKkAD8PXiWbNaaViielY6PS9Xz15bAiCIs1pTnFbfVptQrFmzqFVVzQjqidqJeFupl97Az@Jx9bTa/EgtnlSbZ9jYCbRWFO@K9Wa1dH5arIt35/V3tUZFYMeMcrVROi1W31bKGWgf2hSV95Wzpmi8KZ6eRjpa@3BWqSPyoV4eVwDL4jFsj9gS9bNcrVdKTexQ8FQC4gGCp5ZovKuUqvhQ@b4C3SnWP1oSaKPyH@dQCD6KcvFt8TV0zkg9QhUYl9J5vYInUUiJxvlxo1ltnjcr4nWtViZaNyr199VSpbEvjNNagwh23qhY0EazSE0DDKAWfIfn4/NGlehWPWtW6vXzd81q7cyEQf5Qwbs7SkWoWiYC1864t0CkWv0jQkU60ABY4sObCryvI02JWkWkQgOoVmrqxaBBIGJT76Y4q7w@rb6unJUq@LmGYD5UGxUTBqzawAIAE9v9UIRGz6nXOE6AFz8CsxqKcy0aTlE9EcXy@ypiLksDBzSqkluIbKU3kuYZdLDVBLQB3sPm2CNdaOstv7p10ClsWdqLl//886dSrVwRCXVumAg@nMOu8ypyMKV/g53G/wg/QwcAXefqpt/Gi1NQYversVA18voWZkAwMfb6wnjgrFrKblRhY6Pdfl9sF@uvG@22aa1TM4TGYzUouScIaw@UMmUfMaoMbWgoVBYKTPeDEKGOvkFxsOdMLcGOyFSSqf8Nba54JbspstmuI6uhKQQBK7EU9uCpOxIArItLI1lhMVo8aJKkHvo9kOxAFVMKfKbThtfYcy7kevDP@NfgB28O2gtYnVmUzmb7zozRAAVVNcONkIGJ/pH2HdC@SJL3HOenfiqnN@eMu2YGbxlCD0lZh8rOnOGwnzIfqX7l9CPV09H6hCwaNVVWXI@DC1i7QMbkczBJMiHHJTOlnqXwn/aM/pgKG7agoaGEmiITvFSIUt9w9VbuEsnKhkKQqHmQUeZ7W/y@@gGV3Nz2zn7k/Rv/Pc8tdBpE/1LY8FpU75L@vLnkAjDByLIJJBlIe2M2q9UBsYwESr/wHRS8xkJ8SxLu1dcO7etAEhBkb@yh3ibuxtPBXMce1uHX9eLb4/OTE1g6EdudV7sv9/YN/xDze4v/fsR2yMOTznAnsI@DnEaftFlSAsGHZormjh@wPzFwNosFMZhDDRq9RKuZfxURCwmcM4JkqQPsroepE8ZoBkk4Y7o@icyZTw3Fr7EzUzJAKtRVE3szwlvuQcS3QVYiHpCHpniZOYzaHP9B2P70V1Pc75BkIMli5PMKnGs84XUvgZXopK3n3oz5GASLZBKKj/lQ3KcB3q0k8gV5jEi/JG9rowiCLQ40zlcadqoJSDyNYiGkHkre3dDEO7LaSuWSzmLhzfeS3@Dxo3QXIOcB25sVZw0g44lfE3XgQNGVnW5JyJcYXIdH1KqlA4EWBFMiRXNPqqq@mVWbDYQKRreidSoMeN@3ykabREU4@bck6NvMqWgKRTj7kmPlb@DcuO5IKPvKGit/KxufYFi@yZipdue3YagiH32roCJniExfRQ@C/yfSJAb@AWicAD2gluZSsRYlCSrTCtRXIsrgThkxNMtJQE391ccAzL0@MNd@x6RlaE6uBEgCOToL9eIjOZH0UjEEQCY30bNAm79d16FbiGFnBtXpbwlTVkcbzLgzmqSE3CvUVrEEN713aZHYZSm7Df4whUmGWaE1eApVxd9YcbuiWQ8qU0SVF8@9BIMzlTU1u4nnGcGEJy5FiuTVZA84KydnmVoH5MGVtuF0/fMnEEvvV1oEN4XmcBRa@6VVTREKQB8hPsv9pChDV3SGrudE/Fc40X@TfArQe9@SF@BJBwD0NEAXJ4TzvCvk3XLO7A43iCFDJ8eHAJpIPSffC2yEjyUCwUEtt2YGSEvb6p2P/Zywv9OwPx9zjAn9LAhVIsM@JhLDMV4OCDxDF/aKt/YCUB6u121msexmw7XEnUORPGyWkPUx6LLjulMQHW3sN@BoDRZmRnyQRgdn7N1MpTcI7GeDqbRIKKEfmpnRfdtEC9xmOHaDUPMGIDfM0OaC/EFdGjn2WDqIDObpPZEC5lU8eoQsTG4t8628SB0EXw6AJuTkRUQ8EHuYkIxKMUGlA5ZDFBx4vnIBs8Tldg5ELph@d@70J9z7UQQad52u7@elgYQXapCqY/KY6cy46xPXI4sGDAVaQHxK5NmQdmV3frpDyRv26JeSnUBAx1eJwNcIPcGoJ5/fjs@kEio2FDCubB2Yby8Ng4lU2paOVr7rVX57l1CJU7juVypj5HsVNomLxMXYX1IK8gbP50p0xCdeN/2nj/jEN7g5h889nD3wBu3nUgRFhFFmRZvt8jpH@OF5xYeBM@3qNlGQZLr2BM1vpPq4Y@JFZTqUThQde@Y5C9AAOtnBPEsw2qm/u9fjdskd2v2BO7BBT8PwijmvePi4oEccsP7UvfMonpjzDWmFuovgmazh8lAbf0uPHfwZHHR6M2eS0o9AZtNFEcNnUYuhY3w8a/X3K@LvSfTE2a@zsxtU8uvIq7ZvvGvQTfdX1n2Rj6vMpwUIQC5wR5HTGTomd9Dn8VC15E5S2nGHKnD1UAENxyuRFrb2@X4lxt8CieiAN4SxQmbpyEPvBGpmKzFudedWlzw6pu4M1q2yg3GrXopeWzamwIRV5Ds8hSiI/KucVpXyS3bn6NWBD4vV5N5@@SdjDwh8Bfr5F3HcEscItMT15GyANZmUCemzBbiQO/OA1mhaiWEVG/RhFxqGgLbnUajhz4tV1KBTRRCKpNPCElfijEyB4oNpL1JtWHLaC7rnOimSJjkKoAhSpCtbVjGsozOr7l@jt4NH3Bxml8GFqSQhpzSkV5GqA1TC9HkhmJMbHWX2UH18xmxvrztqEQIeSgKGcNDySqYSSnJBT2y@U3hGx1ruFBbjRIR68lQy6c3cSXJN6q1cO2LPueNo3TFXEelThNkOYbPc7BJpDxf4uNg3ovhEmCZMMTrFBh5C9ZWefTaPEnF@2Mb5dthePEKHVTQLzmT9TcUf7y7PfdwUbzG0VG00/pQi3NHla99/32pDx9urVxAJk9WrNq0YbVwy2gt@1EBFyORTaX0KEfdJ3CP06ALlsN0u0E4fn5VEjR7AKwcy9SnkMoT0RDd4e@TgujTpZaAjKVOdT/mLlC9wzq0FHeXl01fosokfGCBKxU46sEOxBTcYrAgfUaxFL9VGt8A8rkTwdMQ@u8rzSSLqE4xiHKRxh917W@1FOn@5z5DmPiTQKviy7QcgyVdYrNWeE5QlUsAUjyGF36Oltel6/V59bV@gHEDg2vTZu8EjeJCmsDN4u3vnGv7RP7XnKAMHTcmaoRkVnghtWhpgLoCW0h86rK6i9DeYMsfDQ0pOI1Ag@HUK/2zJGugcvZfzqY1V5t0FFjEluXm2mZgRjaoEDMW/kfxyKrKoS4orAHDkvWUwP/IAAZ3ECHs8FBg6vVmI80KIyjGCiod5nJbwknzMAh@SmO9IVFlgZ1crkYsr8a0OIx0LBASL@DIBIiCzxBcJoMBGF4uLVuJlfH@CEiAQK95nisNQyFEJ09AfOSYgZcvLmcGK0soLKyc5mD7u7Jqhjz5/09dvc9rXXPQr0MfHsJXOR7@@yoW@hprd3g5XDdUEeph6q6GPQApTR9hfFb7u/wxyCdQcyJWEe6ApGSEpQ/p@YTZD0DJBb8v86IkDNHEcKRlDwaPDuHSeVEWlfrU5YC3k4v6wO7tI0pEBesJ/dW9VzIbCREZeJC/G5GjPxl1WCEliTeBWj91CTZe8KdBwQh4noN8qndbtiffNkxNdCRZXC@VoNHKmu7lcDpn4Sg8lUH5baEoauNlw6WzvZjjMTu7@Pn1/laW1H/NLDz23oDRoB4YEJoWXcad9jrNBHKAolk4DgUfurYO6/k2vpwe04AklDh4MG5dkX7GuoA1o4Du9vG9ygP1JsMH@EzuI/fun8Gffnc2CpoSijqGgNlDv4jahTs@APPiih75f/kkVAcOFWXkzwb5lHh59wh0E48RosMgZ1ESzkGT/xBtnOHQt8QEzkj1NkEUlUuHkRK@Q4yJ4wohEQRejIXCYJZzbwTA4n/KwiM7rCE5tTCpqR3nZY6RB3elX5pNUovVDArYV6PIWdnMLvX0tkegnTOl6vwZY5kNAe63SI3uS6hCdooVhq5czOHgCjF7krVjdJ1TEJJuYpNnjpZGo8ehmfnQH4xR03SRZQEUG0PBST1YU94mbuJjne0jDHMOQONEtcGvVuN//uqXx65bF21mvt96qSEEVPLCftSJyXNnXLYh0BkAzUE4/oCdGV/4jDdP6JBIIxQIOhj4trztYoY0VDON55/Dnu1SxWBTPJltbolg8hgdM9HNcFGV8cXwsyphFBX9/c7i9u7vPa27Z/AQvj9XLe3EMMPjC2c71tAw/4dshBrjBdk9a5LPs4TNr/1n78OBo38u2iseX2WwfnvjOpWxR/sDLmLLH9KP1g18ok8lkn3U@Pfvmfh9/t8qXyWdXrWeTy2R/H7kMyFC8mbnVWdoO3Ecz0ytjg3cB7S35kSo928NMrrKqUOkRRvb0J1hdCmKj42U35FuP43Bpjd3oONp7Z4yJUECFVyEcUVXewBD5kb1AczyMTsdBBzzYbyiNK/mBcn0@W1GG@7GrFfBPVTYIASmz3joAGk84FtBJbhjjB9KDseeM0QJ@SzIvd88wbPg7mLUl/2Z/kLckbF6kxGZObFpiM5GgP3hjwuaF@Sw7wHs4uJh/l0JwtIBuhsIbkKBH@gNFLkbIbRjPKAASIalwaCo8vhldofFZaX8YPinD172@8YQuhmQTCR0yYZWNT8/G9zAsn6DEfcJ4QuGMecz9wYJCW2ox1Jh2ouKPL4pAtseOAEHLIyZIwYUm8aQPKvOZX1a9kWNtUGwmAUay1l@f0LzHF7AXPaOYznxEl8KgUQp@5Le4N@5z8C6hjV@4/QABOlBhdTJHYSPJjSSedWAEZdBL6qagGE@9f5L52Ndh4cywYtD8fwqNCejTE51wz8b0js4x6SPTPzHwj1e0phJclqLt@WTG0KqMboazwWQoz7yIRDhyfmv3PJNwRAkQw@EI6sLyDCNDAWY@uHMoDFkfFg49Xoiui13nmSDTreJ0MDN8cqQRIftDCub2r5G5bWYHiIliB@YBQsp35evZg6GHJJ@pvK19e3qFuRYoR7MYzPjcjOx5mFcngrHb85HOEGRyOQ/mM3RlYzK1@yPbEhtnbnNqL6qwbYHkM@tkTOjhODkjJHDyyabjuqcQ5h7JISGK@F0hzyGM3h4uZLA5jy2OBg0GDamaCjJBA06CEDsRJZ1fQ2MVoWPA1Z8xCDrKS4u3fxopl1haedHTSEIKugD/0DRbmjqGakGfO/7ESRiMqj8zFS/ISje40Y7o4BdWckzqrdqmmo48HxSwXGL7uDv1nbEd2pwmQ8PgxCTPsvuC90Wcz5TYg72R5P0@@Zf5IH8AYgVy5A@hBDcy04XbY5nNeJJKPbnwZHD8hr6PoPCc8X3xszayqjwrp3DwESXlOx8PeLGM7FADpj0wYUZUyfMfIPSGdh/wW9zZC2TFi43Ud0@zZuuHi/HlZupi/OvFLyZhIpdktcumxYY8zFYrlpwrsDNmrdBP5ZXmCb6bXlyMwwUuxuTWxaf3kgSASDbV@iF7@WsWELrYMM3N7MUGEyQ0ZIhJ9uH2sgg@u4TmRhiL7IbxxNw01eCnvsubAvZW@otjyC9M/gtYKKWSzPSg50x7AIpigOgWAlTssq@2czvb@R3QhPrOPD11bnC/TXs3V84cRAkP1VnYei5@CXFDiBD3c8/eh5dz6OegP8ZU0DSinkxoIZdQOc2pHcNnK6iTYZ6A8kDlFJIAQ1xMv4yNh4@o8FsCWE6VpYwW7DqocV8K90/PHWE7tofrWjQ6hDkSvQzYR4RMqGmELBlvJYeaarokKdgsI0rXDgwyAoHhzW5ou8XYHaelsGZmkvsoRGPUzBBz@0bn6NIUDc3QZ1KYSj4V@aPvXv73/679vDHbONrOfpjC39nGzxt7rzb4ER7g1wv163bjaOMAi@3dbyyyoAPD48v//j9Q/@jvAAe/LA7gn6NdBWtvsXGUPqQqv24c7cFDfnsb2v2///Vf0IdnrLFhZptnbUsQYvuKIiV7TLwL30UVe8lqaTJYVvK4sCAM9jAE3Rx@oGPUfPtVjsx0G9Kr4hbdfwa9me@PIrd4csyakasQWzKUPwVIRlzhEBtIM0jlQtETmu@GcttA5g3QFP98ntnzQAP4p3Tn8Jv0XTeee@gy9IzVIhjAFLcI@jw/HOW@S/juHYWE8inZVyIkqnZyrX31Yh/Y4Z3rzAadsJeEmq6jjn3nXGWQDzNO9wZ0qrE3dH@cZm@BJUf57VfZHhr3s@THnZ0QpPRkkfkFBEGZjQQUQ3I6tcQURsAdwV94xhwlINCf@GdSKjsHSNkTp8M2rHCGJyjSaJYr9brFx8PYnUwgSqfoXxDgMQ@JTKuhRZ5fjKFmrV4QiS2/IJcjnddEbN6Rc6xMOpJmb1jKYAsCDPUBrYOqP5nitE9BSFRrChC4SMbudtu2/JYyniRU4LllPLl2hpPDBPmGQW/wHjKQ0CX9WcxcCSU9QAtCOk0LHcIaOTMbVPTDBL1BfTxoYYY3FPBZK@nGtLr4ZO3JslKr7x6e4JnWA03fcdN3MKIoJQTt@DwT5MIZC70Yry2HaKqcOm08UottGFrzVAqsaYb@IAYeD0u1h2EJsjsUAQlUC7ojvcr0YbNIFwYeuXM4Zo9Ni5wHzNgIgh8tVQI4q3qWQdkJ281wY7BAnLljp4AeynxfHEZAHKqkLYMxCUBLn1XssARDfahNHEZTEQo7YsltaQz7IQkcGEspgAQDx@NNLfDBNnj38EFLOFpCnwQaXhImslSvQMoWFVTDUaCkWtw4amZsp2p1hJ@spydzAeHySC8Sufz2i53dvZevvsWY8Seyt/FgsFIGtYDJtQ0wSKJOgZKN7w8PE8kEv8KEXstNIvQ4sHgAh25ddyZhxY9PD/M5CSyXIFh3lJiKq0tzJYEMIE6dDO4IoKOkpolU6rtCCzt2edE1f4X/EpaqzQyHpmZ7OPjFZtJr4/COAyIozdHIGblTPB7HhdmmzC6YVx@2EP6il3XcXt3B26nQ15XZHho6dV0MSpi6N/1rnTsybO0XTZgwQPDZdFEgDeq1w5GipFNrWKEsKg0OVS364lDBay33AJ1ycUtAmY@BwzSDyYBe/rb0NMXZkYRNCPM8YMQqHiFqrqM6OxN3jl1ROStHEZOZ0AaeDzeje7aCcAf7IYCv1E4w85HW3SZQF6ZEX/ZarUkWG/RJ95ULXA7LAVcg02OsdAfTemlUUWs1yQ2z1ENkyRMvDvyEdkFVGEfEKwZmPvc4KVVcq@oFEkQthNKa5C9iln@eo5MswEkfZJynyMuJguYj@nbgeZTPWzaWMKVHKRWCgfT4VCIOINptcgnuSK6AI0qPFUpjxaPNt6OSyyTeKMoD7GuqTmzJQU@aCihqnDOL@LTA/lfPSpYoV@Cfkw9lCwXl4@I/sN9@wqzV@OYlvvmCqJ6oISCCSjMc@dyiz9TPGKIEzJKzOH1JgCAuvmTYwHokeSMFK9UTSXue1K3Q3L4MuALZ1ZZCuLKOykmCWVPIBvJEKu9kOpO5FqVCX2Dj1fJKsyULq2nBJq6HJ7ZGkydBqz4kJuUaILajINIKRMDtTwKGZw90krxtqbsoxq6exPN0iGVZoQKx/SQLZA/z7ErKPMQW25Ittgs4jg/xBfHtg7zBd5eFmeMR3nj6ZbyRXp850v8WzFH5c7jjheSOFwVce5g7xp2pQysSRXRSUjs3hmOuFrQHt7uD/gDtQz3tJ3YiZ2kAaMGjK8lsigfJ57BvK5YTkYr/sBXdj9BJaHt3z/jCzu/Izu8UcM2lx7LzP7Xz6d@487uy87sF3GtiRl6KdjL89bfrcSASpsIvYocXxV0uZn5pT/dkT/cKuJvGDPMf3tP079TTl7KnLwuYMYEPHDiF68PczJJIsVGqVgN3i4zKQJzCrIDxXGmi7oW3SVuiN7zxrg9RWhdfjP8rif8rXI3oqY5ktbUYZV@XZ/WUg@VZsuSL8zDIinvC/ZWhXnp/5YYV6CNyg@JFmgxbU6mogEBu8cfgtCkTyI/B6utvPuvizGs75VbizLCaAs0aYd4MpjhLvlRYJWB9wow8Q0taqVk/3fpfTIaR/ZOMQgPkcWjv8J4huZPoKhiOFb@WndG6g7AbUucIsYokJyE7k9HePrs8Wb2qUWKLyL4YryTwURunS8YMVI7mAUQmI6BNRtZXWhW65ir1gt9A37lQfJdlj7@IS7@VXPptQdSlYrCKVLY0@EleDPS07d3dh/YArpXBPzgBcxaUf2BW/b/gcGHZ/aPYQ@q03zqet6ElizL0PN1cRmAZES5TvIEy0wJeGTO@Qv@D937yqW1Dy7YMyopnGKW35QbaLuyrTtfp9a8HP/40GruTn6fe7Ob2br74JZ8wDJWcP2Vy1kLlfSPNFMv5mhPTRCRpc1rL2hyAQMN8kq0mYUNIMp9Pmq1CYfvSFDg/R5yPic8HAgAkoo69Id6TRG4WfvZwGkr2YIjG9np09O/NMOYcSJYa2qOrri3mBYH@1@m8JdAbTL7tACGBRGSHSXVg9ZyYpkn3wsgrJ5I65ELS0n/qXZ32R1W2z4lEQqIEP6t0IIDGFr@ob6FpkcnlUmwC8/GXQTdsKWGbjF9TptZDtUDy6fbOpVkAMn2gL8jw1/ZwxieCqV9M3xPGmfmRBLh1lniRw10kZ4YCFzSkD2gD9DtmSuYITrm4v9q6GvqutePDaAXgL0OFQ7TSfmzB1PdDdwAYTAX32HWHpzi@qgVLUsMSr4LOBJkQMaz5jT3s@aOgshUP2KkyxDvhPlIOWaR2aGAihJDE6PkrXRBMfY3NutJS7NfHwwbA@IrcFZZA6fhipaUCS1xCa2gopw9tGtF6PLzejNOJx3QiYM6WjwTliA74TXu/Ib6v1WH0b@3pAA1bbG3LQxsZJwPzs08O/zM5mWITFcnJtb0L88qHTDPMXEIuvk@rUE4tvwS9V77EBmjdwQ7g5bmqC7ib9Sm74eNIr4HyA9M5xKEMFtn7BLYjn70VU@f3pFCXTCLSUn6Mm3Zh7kbWnqKPcepVZLAVHXB67SG51ItLlleCz69wnDHnGOwBU5vdyTbE@WwAi/gi8Gkm4YYcxnQpi5IQMTDOzR@dwJ1rS1zJHzK/jsRUWzyQNpSn/9oMEo2v6JwC1mJ3jC3xEs/ciSF8iCDA4QzIm3ErIjbm/8yKbXN1d6EU9tNbFiwjXQ4Nanx33Rsdgdyj/QzKqyfYQ/R1fIkQg8swCyxDUEutdB3GvUF@WuZsPJJqtzH3T7tNqVbabZQf2u0kt8LChCYEafdeFK@6N9P01L4e2fb479mO56Xx4u3JzDA6QNaDA5GsnJWTGGrlf8pMFjAO6c20kHn6BYkc@MZIJMJRpqVGQzRK9eq7pqBvBo1Jxx0OHSkeSBmpNu3iHaHlQWemxCaW8tSvkY1phQy6lFKUPK9BuHAPcXDbbXT/b7dTnjPsaaOzETzBf2@ab09FkxIONisNyofYiCmKMDIYAEnqKSJ@8LRcKzU/vqsAFUfDI@NA/YFCR1TvYDaYDZ2jgyz/5XfebIGiwGLigBYo32XpJdTNcuWDK7e7gD/dwa2gT4cJdfRfmDogbg1unX2orNOWEOy57ixAMAv1EaiElmUEVQW9MghytXJNFITdxSMbEASV8oCTysPAkEFvIZIvkpmBR3p9ygy3LG8@kdJokn9msMWkJZJ3W8mYrT88EI03RaDl69PacfEUM369q9QxjeWqsbjqt4FpUIKlaxmS4a8cnuaOQ0IFfZlJiTX6MVzqexKNw@8@ht@t6Ea98rqK@RxXY84kPRSfcoX8ffjTLfpUxX6hSyjo2/0yBitQOTktvn4QC1TqlvY9@ooW5tivK5qqnb2uYQpKTJ25qkV33AdNo9/GlmPIqz5j0228qMNbi96q5eNa@QGa94fcmWij2BhOj7WaKtXOz1YvDtJFOB@GsmH4iJ433503jXBNf7GCCUPrlCXm2lKlTS3pkzI3V8E/LjYqonJKGU@1T@TrMnRGCrolFhYvKqCC0trpeCC6WCpRIYoxhWhcM12tGrsc2VegP9/MnH2MAy18up/M92fuRD7gVMMcvwWOdU19uu86fXP/wvh0n@C2DxPA0ImjT/e8WF2Mk3wVzSwlEdUn8xLePtKmESFGuVKvvq@UFT0a2udQSSBataS@@vTqDKYdjJvTKEb5ZyyZfSZmhFJLmzB9IcozhCSBYMowGH5Gv6v@FL1q0zTJ4e3@lYubH@zC3cGNV9jNPd/36SIRWWqOQVr64hhJuh4jJ6gOo3fZn9jd36xz1BeEXX@wQyDWglZ6NcTEFfDf8Hfv4IUhR/TKnc3cUZrSWqvh5Vqh7ziZQp99ADC5VtfGjzFVoz35EnIvkWwt3lLTjFI7n1RLvMk3QOov1uu1D43IarjEl/Z06t6dT34f1hQ5NW7wJClIq5hAuglY1wZdcWHQKkYX2M38ecm1tGIxhXgoZakLg8vpzI66BGFiZrfpIsLg11dNZiJa2b0b/0uSDXeP35VmYTrVsdIfR6igdw/QKcQ5Kwml0fwP565TaPtfkmg6C/5OVFu95lHK9gfXvECAaVa@b0aFFiQ/3UutUx5ffBnBl7dfvWuBQEgtrGAPia@Pdrz69sAK3xsMh6sEX1/Fmy/Ly1KiXFFTU//mq@TleqVRO31fEeXq62pTvC@enlciYvMUz4ZuHT7Ilk1NnT5eCAH0oxMqreGkpkB0MLSC4uD4HIuC3fA0HG1GPd@gaYmew@Egg1nS47KGblH18/2M3bET25JqItDLC3EpnqKgoVry1yRar@hLuM4d3g56KOHKA6Ffk2bU9A7FpFtPEg0zHCxB3rZ43SreY7lsEB5KGxqPUoi@AWURcP7SXF6ErtetvR1XW5IiclQIEs21GTHPhzvngWK33Lnt5c4Bwb6qexJBtGtloNEUwHsYs47r/eGIQZuPIwZa4R9NNYxqCVHOjOjyyycU5IKwiktkwy2aBeHTMBn09g9nQZFUK2GcqUm7tKLAsvboerLOFNXPUYOD1PlTVOKtpQlsPjaFS@5wecjyK/uXnPavQKe36P9NfxeJPYu3HrrkIv743lpxqv8QIPOB4Y5dCiObQvWsXHlXOcMracQ/Kh8/1OplNAk3oluDvPg9MoS@JzaZUD3d5qwbWFUFLkbZKGauuicK5JhrMXQ7MCtwJMhYRjvxPDhqZPAc/AIP8ubl0EmxOoinZYLMGckwNZZgMJuI5XWejpm5QwhuZ5kfKJPmQ5OXq@P1FEt1F2vWzcfUxfz067a9vaL@uu2/iKtPllk2Fkl7FWLEfxYrhGh/vdSHCA0wqwbo4Um@NHzm7zuA4t9vBMn69ZXjp4xOf9QgvvprEP3/u5quWXknrvJwzcq7MZVn67a8F1d53ZZfrmRc39S5zL2WiFrsPoOdpd3trxXpT1qRlN3zoUUpftDQ7vfXsP2Zw0aW188fODJE/jVyf@bIsS3484cOraF/jdyfOXJkj/46CQ4NkZFBJANpFD9U3aPYhdth9wq0axKA8MeHREi0aEZQCKyZTmoNMpnrNobq5JcphF@q630po7HTDlq9pdlaKI91yViFy1W9DntvvC@eire1cvUkzoNjiUCe84dN6W1S9H2yBZZc/EjeN3FGs2mbTctrU1XEAkEnQX/MMbw/dpKhX1JLFb8k27BsP8bVmv1l/XrmGr7P0nP3bupi/LmHNyypEO@RPdM40LejFMt4qfJp7bwOA1tvfMZE77q/z8C6k5V0ZBPnl3D/LTvoqzUwykn@4sqTOtozWQoxg89byXgHbc3USbE0vaFrB6jRW0xyz6@XTL/hNtJf00Z6vTY2v6aNzfXayH5NG9lsXCMrlqVy5fj8tciKxpvah/gy9MW7xgui8HanztRxxquWsPAaBnV@H16PtZz/aVbAyA7hj4Y/OyKVHrXfy@XoJ5BO/Hss9EVIGxwePh6dwVilUF5reOgCtD9wfD5nv4gbI6YKH1P8pvRcYYs/q52lyQAfMsTzHfa@Z6tukvc8TBIorfKeezPt6OcplJoWx4i/BJlpU0uRUw/uYHibUtiBlkN8MM5L5Xug0FehMony3SDxfMuOqVsw4LGNBH64X9OI7@W61E5oYVLiCXHnxTh@M4nve@xiGXg7t5YcgC9bScQoeakYkggRC2ZDB5ROp7HKpyQzarLw6R5kQgIFj/er8YjxAI7FNdbreankal/mZb4PmjdXEnRpnGPhRUJOfODLrtPmivgxfyLIHM0h9pDnSHR5hH6RROHBI7d5KJVzuLZIWnokz0py8nFaIGtaYg5LEP4bt@Cv7TIeOxHWG@B4x3DtmjK6TNhYOY9ouR@qw9WNmLkUCyNcLU5iw5NfIHg8tVdsjhpfLwUjEkdILYDP2JeOEx/ifKoax9aPnPpH1oeeUiyCiY2n5/7UTibvV6wNPMeovn95AlLFAqKbcXGKOm5Hq1AjJEjb8SRdQM9cXRILafFKKXPl9J1Q1rkA@uq5JXfiCVLlzB07X0BC/vsoEWM4MDyBfX8Te8lGoillfLRNYkWaxAoKIPLPuCk7IaH6tTwdZtdV6LCOWBT1SrEsGs26ODk/K4nqWaOJL2on9OG0elaJOdVZxA@Lvv0pgrcUtS@D1I9rr7xhQLwh/iutwqTNK4LLsZeebsTs/tg/wuWPzDGifShaK46yKF7GE1aNUOFxGsRXbAHsy0ARH1w@CGjAOTH@DbggnhoP88Wj2oCmEYxd4d1gUi/cTJw56CBe0lx3jWoVdnhZwr36N9opNQEhdqdcLXbELEZx0vIKe566EuMzBo5JSPfBx8gWUs1Ut2QYK@cdFcivsPsFbk5yQYh6OIWGJ6K/FY9h1S2WmpWyeFtpvqmVG/6niDMvxulGo3SXQ9@0EFwzEpyfvHL6N@NojCmFvo27a0Lm2NnYsNYM5WqKD3nNdIYu0GgJI7r9PbkyWq9UPD0tHp9WJGmiAXtzpyP1WMz5257Ys@toD1iNVRG3fjHY7afJSPaXV8koejqESLdoMCLvQrq1rBcpgoQ2jccizzleHJD247VlU0FiHK1chukQpLYxDcwsahjIBSLdEem8HpD@VIs6put0ZNp0fm1heqSxc0dTzfaT0hr/EwK51wyvzMnoylxccGWOYivZqZ9CoveDGMvE0U5uV8aDPxYXziSWqY7CQf5i4g4X/aELz/AAFM92ndvs@GY4NHDL7w56vfAg6M9H32zjjZhO59oVgM3/Bw)

SSL has `#` comments and treats CR as newline, so it executes PHP/PowerShell code.
`p` in `print+191` breaks SSL, so I placed SSL code before `print`.

SSL code:

```
$avdxddxdxz$x
```

`$`/`$x` are for Pyth and PowerShell. Spaces after `print(349)` and `exit(0);` are for css-script.

Answer (score 1):

## 422. Befunge-98 ([FungeJ](https://github.com/TieSoul/Funge)), 18330 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [RubyFunge answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256783).

Build: remove lines matching `/^import (com|javafx).*/`, then `javac *.java`.
Run: `java -cp Funge/src com.company.Main polyglot`.

FungeJ is how it is [called internally](https://github.com/TieSoul/Funge/blob/f9c0cfbb/src/com/company/FungeSpace.java#L540).

TieSoul also wrote Multilang and RubyFunge.
Like RubyFunge, FungeJ warns about unsupported instructions to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## 424. [Nim 0.20.2](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/releases/tag/v0.20.2), 18393 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyx" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]g[>++psg--.--._+._q]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>] (  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"$avdxddxdxz$x${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2");print(349) #\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print      (not inspect.isfunction (lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0); '''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+    =x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +     +8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ? R`"12"`"420"
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ? R _`*` *
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.  0; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;ppp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{ Fenton,
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo if compiles uint64.low:21 else:424#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Exith,8,3"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   Ford: Eni^ x._,_  \;nceppp s
 ; ;:在ｕ∸⫗
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({43175a87-fcdd-4f72-8d1e-745ecc37fe41}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PYdSD4UdHw/IibYFaRTBJPvskkM7OysrqyVS9lZnW3RbJYIAiS6AQBFgBmkpXJim6NQytZsseWJY9sy25ZHs/Ka0@Md2JmLcfIOxH2ROyXCcd88g8o2Y7dsB3SP9Cecy8AgplkVrVsbzgWJID7PPfec88995z7Qlfzhj/9aQIv8sSxZgPL8YlveD7pueaZ4YrkzozsaqZXUHMch6H23MFkZNi@V@USRCHE0uzBRBsYpG9avuFmiWcYpGtYzjn4q4RsT@yJZ/QaYMsRYhvn5NDWzR5AIL5zatjmS8MFvzwhdw3rcnTpE90ZjTS755Gxa9o@9S0Q8kQDS3@inxKt6/mupvumY4NXcSmJ0pKtTMhDx/UMgOTohuc5CKuyFESRybsapDe2jOkVyIpCPjANt0doLsauwfKiqOT9k3v3rrrmyOcFxyb3MIdXvPJkb@I7h/5V@AWyNzBsjahiRVSvehYBT75hleWyfNWrBFVl@KZ@NZ0y2ev3TdsgD6GsVz0rRPc8wdNdc@xzUJXknulCNWtBdRJds6HasFK3iDEa@zMiMELQLCuqZI9oHpl4E82i4ezJqGu4YUDP11zftAfk3PSHxB@aXhSPhvbGmm4IPcMyR6Zv9IhlQiSnH0AB0HaPnBqzc8eFug9gOrY1g4iGbvZNjBLmAwDilfKHBoMz0mZAOLYPVEI04kE2LCOEluYSEP6u0Z0MiDPxxxOfQN56pqd1LQDanZGe0dcmlp8lXfCDKqHu50PDDqgawIkA4sRhufpoQrNmLIhf6/WIDAQN@Tg1iAlYo9mqklwO3InjAtYgVJijABglcFZGYwo1DHXWd6qkIMvgfxC5YG41y3OCzCxnDT1taLS0zhDuE9cZuNoIsNEzKE7fP3xCPN1xwQY3hmUN6yYwuuaT7W2SPHh0N0kaUbWIbpeLqqhOLqAKEqEnOdOsCVBIvCYcqB83is1hlSU3klWSBLSoMsnnSR7ab5moBUCSIlfAAIxAzSlwF4laJnkF2luB5CBwToXGXQQfaBAkLxeSWUy872oD0zIY6AGCLmHbgTgqPOU8yUGzyBVzLPTAsfosqE5zUSK5MimWSKlASvCskIoK2cA089BiCnAX4QaIFcgjAFJzkGNZZcAWjQKIGAlxn/S1kWnNghRoEjopKKQEUKEwCkBXywAF3rkc3jm4ywht@YrD9odQFUPtDMALlnmKvMyI2BnWrwQvaWtLonwTGTNL3hti8oBXwGihTEqQfBEwkocsANrVMiRfkFlBvKFhWUG0oYfRaG5LMtyQ8xLgogxVIwNOZURqCW6wA@tUgUeqwBBV4HEq8CVVBXMOk4BwWFdFqOdiniUz1LxTSIilo/ZoBQDfBzAKYhz5oYJIAghQawRQDTSQByrJIZUUcgTyD3kpFQlQQFkh5TwplwjgsyITqB8F8oUkpAArViA/CgIDOlCAEBTIkwLYVgCokisQLoZsJYf@EDcHcQE1Sh7i5MEMFacU8YZ4QB0KJKlAmqpaWVAo5E0tQHkLOUq6ahFqtwR@gDcV8qoCSSG9qmXwx7hlwGEZKbuUzDJEaIgHqBVsC0CLgIwC5IfChbBgVksB8WrWeKh1kfGzmN0@Ri1iGykiGiGqjMWDdx6xCVmRAQy2Bsi@ChSQo00J3vkoeUsBIE0Eb/RMyr0t7EGUCEOlLCXIj7Sxv0CbUqQ5Gs/8YeSmMjcHuKoJnNEYaPos8oRWmI08F67FHLqqlBEvAMl5dPWA7ToTz1oAiQx5lSZlnJnWwq1M3XqG1uub3vDVIq95mkjX0HzbPF2kUihkY0jVYh5F9FhyKuXiYX1TgL5sMETToixqCcOMnaiClrKsKDR7XaM/sQeGUCnH8kd9/InrQ6@zSLPCnF1zMIAefAFHydJi0l504VygObRyOejcQ0fELqbpmtC33yb6EGSTyLPC4FcqCxg5FWHMtC52@QLIatBFVLBT65tT0r2t0y5lkcEcxZM@NMdh4OrawLHKpYlMy8UYbVDMvSzLEXvGqy1@5Jh2KkmSaW7OQUfE5M94Nw693QfYhWGnjKQLna5DRYoF@0zZYbeZBqQtSwDQJVsoKXUNXcPuGTsrg3a2IRzTFwkkAkKk4ZyhcEt7zKVkPNqrdl2UZUEE6hmuSzAsCMBelva/3qTrGS8mKGQt8tWHDt2Afr@vmVaUAdqPaD6VDuCd9CC92XK2@64zop3NCPtXy3HGa2QZ6M3PEdB959xYZH3R2WvjsQUiFbgbTKKDzJxrVCqnInw8VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KRBHTNXSK@6DoEDsHQstyFqtEbdzOIZQ7MVkrB40F5BAP49gTy6qCEGToJNeQesaZhC5MHluWwzAPoYQGclYAoquB2I05p7mIIN1WRSr7nYQ16zmj5aKx/vUwKvrQRKnJOtdmUHt96FqNqTYC5YCgBA4tl4yAYlgNYk2AFoHFOiQ9x076EZRzFyRcKHRUEipFI058c2SAjuRAFKzxPM009u40Z90ZkDLFVl6kShHLyRVEidxVRDGHfMyBNRaQBXsTHbGGaZs2pSAQlzxUAFxglcyN813SamlwuyDsjQM9UEQDBjzGrMXUCY@19kAs1ylEFGAN2wMNxROJiVoaUP7A6QOxnZtQdmBYEHUBW6dIQBRETlNRFzmKciSg0alFTKKPxwTcoVMC8rwnl0E@dT4yyUvwtIagX@gT152R6RhqwhxBKF93@n2g3pfGeAggyKhH9JkOzRMqmVKPN7S1MddzKJvRx8uFXdg2DQhjo96y/@TnycAA5INM20etEQl/UYzxmBaEIkSzmbxra4AvLIg@nlHkcIlFjL7jiOjecwyPkozjnkYMABPzjAFtINDa@guWNEL5HWjVpnpHD/hP0MgQPibIrSwMJhXQwruGDQ1IB9qEpg@ViDW7R/qgkMcEWVRFNF03xn5ALQ5laqYdUwke30OVgLoKATDRG3Kbu2T7Cu1A0Ih@YhItqkiY9XGgqWjIcQOtX6DiR6SVMv5iza4lDyHOrqTOP8cwSzl4zq/Jw5g2DNSPKKuY@MhQkEea@hA5oo88h0rd0ObcyfXig1s8eXdEhH6UNuZGAebDiVLkhPlYD0OA27oOSBxbCKux5IBBlxzeAFrzRisgO1EmrV7cVZQ0EVjjm4COHNtZARWQGcHFIMs@tC4oMR4j79CsiBhpc/GW6gjZ9mIgCrsz6EnHY8eFlsFYz4wONtAqi1FXoKOnoh4jLZI7yx0sdBxJ7PZ97AshwtjSgBawiWFLBf1KA34BrIzp0MD5HJZiLMO01VNYQf7OaQfAiAl6VNs2UEXT3BkDAsWDThoSmhHTdYEZnmFXwXqisEsRKZ1Cz6D1eshfER203V9NXESK3p90zelVRV1HR/EjjzvTXNJHHd0F0QMaUSrZ95LpGnWnMWNevOSMfYlGZU8eAtJAIlR5qg9qP3QV94DRHM9sPcUvNTE@S/iJ3y/zaTBgRCapkfdAYbiaO1QikGhGp9Cuqa1GBtCJCwI8BXSjOUEPSUQPzQVpAxoh6JqVSq@rkUvgHi4RpvtMIQkVE0XMR2kZdi9KK0AE5iVeXpEl4bk6NQixvg1LgMFpyWknsYTAt8QEjciDgyQFPSw6UJmP@VHphjlObDqwR1JMIEmTi0gEhg4gRTNjgghi6qbfCYSW27dD8WWjXgdiA5kK2GYvHddrw0FPETg1BBapTBIkIvrOsY9tI5WG8mLgOcsNCE9AqfUGufCHLrQ4ap9zEAjQytlIySFig3p@ZJ5Oelcr2kZHDMRjqwPRydR9vsaBCMBaQ/0mrCaXsAq6bxKxisSL8Snoa8RLXbFC@SCYa3goBNeDrMRqOIU5CGh1JYpY1MBtQdD7M90KRAJmgsbOuFEXsn8ajHVFjCgbyARho73WUhkQbA4MDnmyd3K/HrRF5il1Tbu65GA5umZR500MzodxHxzeOdo7@vnOChiW2a1edZDMfLmIXe1kKgzsiZQX1epmHMYC8N3OzbAx4nIYngu8ieBMY6LSTIfOZRqi8/HR56@iBCQhRAdNAcx4XxFpWBgQuriu5g2vdMJkkMlAklGUMCwRDkkIMzJg1tFfC/PzZPLyJVbe1UyNA3fMmTXRGIDQUTq0w3giel4RwEKvbp/1iDQuyKKmjRMZC1M8ZJifd1F2vpoZKlDHSObdx/cOjuoUbDC6JtAgkueDLKW5PRFo3pqAIr4qDLA/MOkkIy4yjlI1zetKBOv6EoIXdUvWwAcAqPGIDhGsUVg0bwh5379aNuoq6BEFUDuFcFWujMtD@mfNaCwf2MXpqPiu6kWpx6KzipxW9liR73K3pRcKRilfiXdb@iLNXhwonTeAfiCUG13wOvUEdBEXUmQgVgfZP35wLeMeFSJBFRDCnHkWEWlansWh9iKYJOlJ@6CnOZYhfkA5Hk/4tCQlw6kDUfeoChoLfzA1/ZScZm8lDWEh9b29Q/VuGDgYuKbjGVRpQI0ceya3j3OBugc0YjuWM3DIFsRh0mGYIIhNa4u5N3DsazWkoSMWNYHTicB/cfhGG0NfY76k6iONFVda2cSkZnvnwKWVYg6RRDFEQUk0vPiRdqYBuhblPj784gF0IkpBliOzTC9AQSwORRea9JgrdSACJCQG@VlZwGj@8VprDz2E2AQgFjpgdFHEvYX3SkfKMUVpZfiVWXrPuYbxj5zZFdICF0ZaYIih7PDRkweHjw4e7n3Y8tVCYcmelytFQByk1wVZSBwyvGFr3WJNE4uF4BLQNlxsXsAFJqCghBNKE88Fxi1iEJFlYA3VsJnb1HvO0E566auFOUdf4SNbZyT0EBsfCxpEBEW7Z6Ey4rKZbezPkX6Gvj/2qpIErXw46YqgtEof6Y6lDSQaDzoGy5IUVF0OH@PohrcqBmTGmxksBhviAtFhRscRNWvkgPJC58eRNZAUA0/HrixzMARdGCfRDTctRhRMSyP1QEMAXVmKykYZMLUBboN3WE88I@13FLXM6FqR1bzEh8GWmj@E3egboDqloLcCVKSvWEnrdus2mQGXRkhXgSSIuEUHOTyCfYFFQJCkY6eo54fIodwCR02RV1AcvZjgmC5wKakg50tKsSCBWgZqGsisAo68CSPN14eC7wgAT3D6dNwgRoV9T9fsvrgVGMLMgtx3C4qaaz5rtew2COit2zRvODXdnLWbSjtdI9ejbAXh0zWg3qXiIe2GDkC71AikSd9kDT/radfZWU@jratHJH80DvocYUwe7oEg9dIBft0z4m0PI0hxT2lrKayEgV9JKwaELIzK4QMxJUGDgp4WSE/CfAkg9KJ4CJQDfCsWgSxGMyKBaeYPgX/kSGqfmtLXJVx0zgVcYzkrODQsjmfA8mggZNpCDjMUetAExwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwknLrD0MVQTG9Dah44A1DkPhyJ97IJxzmbCxoaxSQZWHPDcE75INOHlTcJFGBoAv/7DH/QDOJHYJpI7GlIcYOGKZBdEFMlTZAHQl8@IT0caegaq8bg@4qltoiIictRXgK4rudkRfXeD8JDW6z/8k9effOf11z95/cm3Xn/yq68//aPXn/6HDeEV6piN7UyrJYjZZpvwyWuZv3Wg3tq7c@tOmeYQ5EnI/P/9C7/6t7/2S8t5X5Hujz7@2o8@/sW/@aVP/voHH//o4y/9@Idf//EPv/LjH371rdK1/69fdvT//okTJHmOQyPxBIP0ILnhEHrR@yC1NbdunV@QjY0NiL6xsQM1sbGzQzJkB54CPDeg39wB3yw8d0gTfDdIm8zbHGiwHlkx2ifS8XPR0PRhB7ilbqRyaRG6vIvL6SUZDptTEdr5Ka9v8e05nV2ifQHOuLBM72OlHdMlMpj396D7ZrZF5tcl3ZRaTbnVbl2kWr1MujWXskobtOyOiQ8vpaabiigK4Ia8JSWJF@W5FOVtSkNCIFEfuouc0Qk7tmIHdWlG8PfMKfREwCqBkOJj8pS10MkdHFr9ojEeztx4gGi8CuRTHHteLATB9TLI/@L85SWLHxeFlnTkUGJk4UAsxGEvlDTGM8YXOZbTlrS0Dinssc6E/sjxNel9EdQNMdbRJDeSkiBAH0J9GCRa7Iemp4NqodmGM/HiY3Qrhw4xdXA9GU6Afe8PzTFn6EMHKH0XYJJolgSRjBM@Aps2CqP1dBFubNbIMnCKAXpjukbHhMqnrZeOYig06TPNMnvRWHahOH4hRqnVaBwiY0LmwHZcQwBEQAyOLkii6924Rjibe0hHiq7xysCXdgHId03Dz5J7lqNRjDo20EKMGnEuZBEf9FmIcmT0OMsmQh9EC5HVgGv0pC2Ozm067hDYJZQGp2zUqI5GgYfkeOOe6E8hKpfCDiruybQhENLOSU9V1aJe6FdDP6QFQPYQqga1OBtUwtBLUMAzHVTtARtGCXXaR4/vHrCxBto5YXeE406dkdObgBwW6BlHhj3IkgOgItN2RsBK7TD@y1PryHF8phWDZd1IBlMyzdHE0ugYydVhjBvj6U7XsejQyU1RF@EnrqdZGhu0CX333n8IsvHTk@O6WI0FkrSz0Y1p47jd6mQZPg/jM3V0ljKcTvEYYfKbBR67uXBFJTKXwKOMHiNcMwmyYqBFU2vkGAS8UOQ5hl2rbkThFBqOyUiLhC4Ulbqf@f3@knOOOp8KyEushXOeOrN1lEvqkNtdBCqwQLiocilMHFCRhonWVq4NV6Lh2HIOINaFR5l6aHSlpYBD90u@Feq7WGqJ0k/AwaIJ@6FhhRNwR8bIwUkm6CUtnM0A0R4FWbYY0oC@YoxzCZRN4wwVdAkaRLwqaEETGwssNJfYoM2ma9oSThRxmxIJRohrtOGA1s1m9jzGQh3QjOngw3aDzQij5uEypUdiY9ebHQCx3aiFi9PWBcOUkskoGIVK8wYxaDHpJPi1okZLGjw6JM3RKDXOk0Donqqy0JqWDtqXScmjaOgTvtWa3pLVD0EmwWWHm7elgVGj64HW4KsW@iQpww76co6GYsO7@hC4C8lMl1EJ9TOx@47VE9hcEtAaYVoIVlAwoR8thwxWvRqmG66EpEtRWVTkqrFFlNfgXqnSxvUAsWWXESAUH8jlafbskjRPs@RM9MaW6YOIhPLEMFhVZF9doEnnszTX1WYeF6wHqZO9o3ffb8ptBoEbaTg/VGa1OA3X@YLW5joTXJkNJlzV4ps@7fXprL2J5QUhByLQqQTIPsBgCdRIlFBQIir5GJeLsvQN0OdSBhWXZqMsMdJzsW9pvm/YjObYJN16dLPZlCCZOk1@JxiarxKZzl@Yfcgl@EEWa@T45O7B0ZGIAl0qeYDzHFVojiA6gjCyrtAhJuOFr5JbvSS5hXHSqNxy0NRAXe8E8YGoa0D0EwNnc5DtDAw3BY5pnKLQwZnOCtGITBoLEIRrk3Sf4igClgJle4cBq67M/1P71HbOoxqvAsVnKCYB3anbVZQy0@LENl@IHnQvVNCEIIE@Bb1EfTNFOdmmkg4Wn41wghWEaiogQgmaTQI6E78JgXnSbtfYTDmEBT9wQ@zyPK0Kuhy8roRVXwdnEGQohCB6/RV51pSFSjuzuQoUXYgVrORm5Y/BRQjLoD1jZbKbKdrerzVklgc2Y8a491OPLn9c3s9QJZvMwLORWRo8XFxEmQ5di7S8pmh5xRI0MmQldMACCxKyhESwzj6gWepPOT9ovRiNOqTS5CJCuoooJ5eXFIdkUyUUh2BSCKuMeagVA2N64EBpHgRr7OMyAW2twXILbLMtjg8V7eX5TPRh4rp0dkUmFc74eDwmE5r2qUNnRSJTRxaVAsqBUezRqXU9Ji7YpI@loFEeWFh1Xe68UbdPHysC0MmBYNqZOtBh50ACBtFRk47oi45Ar0h5eanFUrLBUk7a04KZCC/eEFKolGngfrdrrgsKSMA1VOF7RTBgUkjPqpgXlUURr67GIUv4DdaWBu//8XEP8Hy9FobQIeA4XGToQBeNNSL011ZKEBUt9LG6Atlw8cQyNYoAanoTSF1zoUiaFRlWg6ZT0oIA3fwIB9iDmgUaxAcIljeQE8s5mx8L36sTWTXFZANr1NeFvbI6iSVFJ0NAbetRJDBhxzRoJMqiWCUYUzYhEVObkV29OVPhEiJCiZbV@3DiT9gTZNs3VqI5xvumNhiElAtaVzEktpr7hip3tdNJzxHGp4NIHi2uCLsoPR0tEqDbDyZHO2hcXXxWQLY6OnyvC7bowqRz@noTVXj2xBsLXapj95iNNoTRDSm4FnuuC2IG294iw3qsmRZ9vCUlBtCBUIK1ARKuvxRiSDOvoNnSujOUNYafncqieXbgOHU9k5FzayZax@P18VGvpPErldWxp6LO8LFqBEBiazwDBYsWOFj1@YZahW7JHGmWoPZixrVMe9U0/bWg0QwfjYMbEuiuhBuJHDsefWJp7sJ0A4lfG1S@NjwddAtPTN2B7n5MlJKoqAvmGC4JW4DExbT0EZv2N1chLNxMIUSm1Y3d0X1cKrmGet6CdbElirgQNEYOorMOJ7pzjvdagWAIyiZ7ru67Xq7M1VuwIcHSLQ165rWMf2mQDwcR30CS56Zn0MdqxJ6uzKivWyvdl4k9HL6LD8e9iYA903I8ckyfNyFo4AIW2HM16cZxaWq2QIey4@YbuE04t7@oUM0aOFaxPJA0eKyt9YnbRw4fvN@Wl0W8SFHewItCQcexleC9loOfSu7pmyqIbtdzcV1nzHhDZ7qKIQVzF@tLB6I@7ltYXbJ7cpnGFCU2xLcmYVzNcq7NwvfP0EmsQ23YSYxnVEAGOQ4jVMpg8F0mNP8sqeVvTq33dkzpGtjSmwoRq9xTy4BuiT6vVSlRZeUzxlBk@e1ZVN@aGBNjperwuPuREXQYb5@4HGR3MxhZx8F83IARhXoZ6HRvlTvsedF2I9PQcPLuzcLJMvMagzw9RqX3CRieoOF6jIE9GS/V3pJeZR8x1AzHYRN1eku5QJ/PylfKb5BxliRrz6D3jboO081woVO9IMtyIHrEZkKWLDfpQLko7kcmey4lTF0WKS/C4uyXGzOuToOiJb6Ubi1LUdep3jRwpSLZpm34M3y@JXfsOo71WWoKmCRuf3VAzxToktGbauya@BJshiCLwQUPhyS6/XXDCqz3CLRCwA@quzdVenyq5q1qU8DJyBFOFC1bV6eBA4eWNur2NJLqnjvp60BxZyYO0rA1o9Z6UTAYnlDEslha1E7P6RqWxl7TYv6meBUxt6JtB3OgOGfKZkoX89qJK7xjPIOymj1QD4bGyKDWG8RrrYeHOQSvtYGmDt7rvKeGoUvTA0NfF2BsQrO28bk0NRuTXXzHBsXGx@VmqCBYuKAxcF2PrIeaazoP9h69G59jDwIcjrSBcS/UDmJDArhehilOC@PqwYEquYNNSYdoAdhAsLRPjZkXvldGfDjToaImo7WNTsfRwbdoZeuWQF7vwuyhM7SHxpCtO45s66gUCMmngAPqsQdDXPI0Hi8thY7jwXIsK44HZDGM4ThOf2UaB7glEnfyrIzP9lkHrzcOU2k@a3xoWEumQ2MCfNxzfGdsCNS2LqiFQxrsuY7nhDO2P@tYyY0aLaAifP@s8N@oWw00xx@P6asztiYefdCoAt2x@iZ5os@WWNDFcI47EF86o64YOIrB@gs6qbu6TXdNXx/ilmFGkcbA6epD802ZDo4pkMLBDWZ9K90NMWMS4S46g0IP6HVnItJLPe5/jK/DdZUejJOwziAy3NC/rxqLoptyhbF2qnts3A9NpIpDn7HWxbbuVunm5@qLiekvgMbW5EQDmWygHQ3r8h4sJVgridC18Qt2GCwxWEulVHhFQVUwZBAQlHXJLq/SijWxXI49VvIG3dFP@yF7XovJYHkKHeIyY4OP4L5EOkvralZK1vZwMvCu8zY25twDaQUf6zVyujw1Nu4K3YJmB691GFQtCfetwbsD4sfEuHFioHDjzAANp1iC5pjw6sALamWydnjIMsceexKhv3beKFhuA2rm1ckthpvZaj0xqJie0Wfj@Gh6k0wG@jUIrwPozwUdp31xGBj5NOu0GU@ynQHwa8Eii8Bh2HW60srlMKurP@rehA8fGQMN18Y@MH1cRbiCKmj7WLWM5o2wvzDRPPMLEyjZOmLDrfhszsyNL6JE2wp4D7WBqd9fqogokwGCgyWI7LVE/uh0vS7Oh6aHy28iww1jLkhyjIiR6jogQq8IeXXwOTqFYNGA2M62laFXDRA74xluAJpR001jw6ZPBxCD9zotat1ipxszcT4ZjSde8FqdB7rAJz7AOmLszDs3AbjwArgmGWqWv3oQNjaaCIJU0N8tjKuTrJIvmpYzIF8sywTkLp@YKOeuIJw70PM@wdUjrr2CEmnabzl3hzq/wOQ27wXUrYHr1G3Tv3kAw/dxJUn4xsKwTsE5B3ngAT7F3c8KQThZjZEHsU4u2lX6hi4aKOzYmbi6gcboqIi4RB5AN/bDhbAmbq7Hoy7O45qN7ljQjMBgrWwaumNPfMGd2Ddy/@KN3L@KxwXFqpukvnDw8Gk6Xut0ufCbBMnwQKmFae3s9hViMm2Qpdbzy@XQodh/lx10c0RXrb4hzh6exqNTtnzXWaWCPJlBR7GKmU9Gdw0d57LemMYj56FjO9C7jIHxjY4Mti17aZXB6ogY7QFuPAY89N6YzDEFu6ZTYdKDNja6UI/WwvQ2fQsDfFfztTVdCx32oipZZHojTZhW13A/ouNZMfM6rXE5Q/eNKVUD1hMGa2uCr@tMesWhpqW2sDS54I0dx2ZPyj1leCkPb@YSwNrp4@1nb0Vc@72keq9UpZaL@viMLV0weuzcgHVldY2uY7HnDQtibJNNVGuuaXjSA9yGTt2KeSKANOXdyCtKN/KKhRYDkumZ5tGZ49VawQKkMv0M61KGmqs7OGkTGG5YMhLbO/4GdhwtJ2ez2V1A/BQ4k6ZPglMd35Qta9Qd0cdaBSBWm0cGJNPDdWvHM9vXptcrkw2@BLvNY8uMoj3aIVvCRl0kqSegXaRXK3BXsGeO6YNy3rUzuHSliGCbhv5Sw4Emh@JlMby65A9lkx5R45rh1lhzoQOhkkY3Ha9sMcvrpkAQsQzBH7qghkv@TSO04YkXK4b0JyMD5z2XJxLWipyON6SFdVZP8UZM1DWE4PA14BnRQWxMrhP21kqMCB7@j@@8J0Gn2inmw1MggEW9eVIZMj9x7eD1NpT2xPH8vjl9DPnGpebr2AYWqwBR4MVaAJq21hUCas@eWGxAYBBb9DPqUTVKoGfmCoJF2bJvCIZ9JtAzuabXS@SwXUTSHh6n6hs9IdiSjoPlwoNwQ1EULHivmNOL80BcUahIDLHTYj5YY7gKuechBwD5yfGFsUff0th7cvjg8Yk49pSV/dDeEJfgX5PLlva4q2U5Nkr0kebGpubYWqie6fnSnWNF2H9wKGKANfhmo/cCvHByaem1digyPFZT0tZqL@hr@KsFvvsnDx9kFvvvSGp/6DojIx333j8@zuJ2hveOV3rHY9@D1tF3pmujHx4oSnoF@QabNNdxyRUprYN0YoAWCcR4nx2R8UYhSnfGRu9kNjbeh04SObX3lskX1xbykXZmDrAVkspaRNGGSipiMZ@OLf8FJdlwo/e6@jw1x8gtdfqS2GvtCgmUEHKSm1stJdw0OX1VWiFyMDn@2SIp8nVqjR/sKmnePzZjiqKsw/Ox1od6JYW1lbUcYNUUp@WcvcVsqBEoI0LkJPhAVYL5xsXKJWEErFvCB46YB45g7K5dmXETgMi5uLLBnxv2TLMFlJYCl7ETSRlfNGJzNdFikTM89XnltFW03pqkdGoM0Xzixrz29@8chh5HzD2wvfvoKXmieaDxrIBoxCAuJIuPBByvwcO81g1cHPZc4NSsnxiMV9N9lRxrbs@xZ9NYU8FZXOzq6PmVURy00UCGZU7NVbxbZ@MzT1avBAnTYCvkndmSnBc/HyOI8PrLv6ooskxPP8G3IjPrFQImKTRpMzw6K@51chiRvo79sggO6ZVa1QNjiisG2CjlKuV0Jf8u3sDbS@n17PImv/INfvkb0rvmh44kJ8rKDQALN/iRghh5P3Cs86Ej7muucQM6bsp65YasV2L8JjiQmc5eBeb1QiuuBA9eK@ntxPDd/HjodM38koi8vI9y7XC7r7l0/cHACRbPM/vqpM4nYUN@qL004k34dMEHjOEEl4yvmEjrgiBm2AOTnb9G7jj@AbXdoC1E20RXzzWb47uT8RVWgkfVX@FOH4BS5px75A5u/FnIhyuUS1xbtNp9nTBFohEmPGrw/slemOjjY0mNpbjIxYdPlpxxa5z/@Djm5hrT6TptS5iuU15W@ixSfXSSX0p2u/Hs7A37KqBnA1YXvdd2uYzvvHd8vXWipjD0R1bo855mGyGcnuPTvVLRONx0vBgc/WBICSDkYysWdEEvYpoAw5M6HTy7pNNZRyUnxod0YBn6SuIbUxTrmYAfHBFkTPNDP/hMB42ytgE4pxHXPh4PTXsaWEYLd1zrRlIfeWGJ98ix5ZyTUOGJNZ@gx4Io2plh37ypSajkbu6Qc/FedwlP7BsAwWsdiu6s6b3vGK67KsyRLt0LLe@r6RUh3jsOA6zy3bccHCTtmZPRKm8aNZNZ5eUuNeyrkcxVHniE/enQce1VnmHFVKt3jLWgN27wG81AW1vl0e33VzkfeM4q54cTyzdRSAs9HzkTaD0hWR24ofTW2G60WmJVXFjxRF5v6KbjLsApRs7EA/HOtNJXgwofmf6S4xV8Uzc8EtiwRdu5Cvc9h3zeXOQzXoiXa7H03r2Fz/I48QRnCunuuIVx3U6p8Sz3RvJ9aQ6oZTXh2eboiu/itKVD17GZLR2f9wnPWloB7b5mmen1E6HqG2ZCkc0xf3KWW9XKgOHfi2P0/dk0kpyfWHTnbmDbV6EAA11PB1@M8OjqSyUXGxRgS0bWLHtbsOwvHIw0PT7kuHTkQjht5C2YeEyzcI8f3dk7@eDJg8D@eW3UDVMIT0lX77JVW9EajSvDKPQceekYn4I31KDvoiMoAm6ivjKD9sHegychOx6CSA6oxKPeYgNNEd8lqZ7raaNKJEE@DPcp3YW2h@YFJ7o/MxxhEhWK9Xer1Py1uweuHhV1c@jYAU/XauOR4R9P3H567UZWdbWyc/xgHVt9Lyzm8bsP3/vCvcU2p0fmiMiiCn90YNudoTeLHyjvZYODjdjxAGxTtieGp/6nUjYwkfTyh5biO8zx2OXUJh47ukl3k0PYy0uyEezgBg8@3BMe7FnH0wlNe2LgpnP2@RW/vgnJ1OtKoUJ28MtGVaLINE387luFHQIXJtYkmxfBfuxqVZmTjTrhqzwJdsRHZzqzc4kBMJ6oCoUiwqlCNn3w2Qx3cxP6oQ1ySej4oKDjwZVgE6X4uRa1YL875Gnz4snhk4Pjk72Tp8dNuT0P9sOHpbBtSC08deNWrsdD4QO8gV7GTimn5zBYkBz9ugKOK3phuQh@WGi5aPWloi0Kxe9gnM0L25YkeiSAJMwhfwLPUqO@KBiBE4MdlphWUHAaRJXtzqeHDEAdMdA8TRMqrUrkVQmPNc@DYgX@V7/DRX3xI25V/IwbJhwcLA1y2MBxekGKnkHefIUp3ts7fPD06ICEGVxQzbnZ84f1SoGdOx4cOcbjAQEWPTsjGURJQl3V68l7SUBMUkySKj3EgZ75jceTJSN6wOMfgthbJLVJ4QMGk1GlSP/jY2meFHEzQRrCJsNMJSFZoHlKKHhA2wkQCbl7dPj@wRHB/B/cpc6IIgRBTnBn@V98v8e@mhGe6xR@wM4dBXoH1JbnmL0qHuugGySRV9TgbJgewTPN2MkHxJjSL1BQyqODHrFP2qXpWTtc/CyK8ICGxRkSWHOUA8Rjsq9b0LMZos9qRF8H4jh6dhzQ@zk9@vDKqYBpevIW@1wfO68zAk1JLzyhHycFQU@ifaXpmXgyBNZD35m4VxoJbtOmh2CKZA@/7YdfENToB2AgsxPbZ4eIBQcLJYBCxYhXZckmzSz7XAwfC5jc3oBG0jVAXSWebYJo5FfJR0DBOCFXZSeHCEIjeS1KCLpKTQIqQ7GATHEb4THsRBgf4GlwLVd6/Su/JA1qBMw@mL8amKfyHbB9LbD1wfx1Zn4mIYFKyWtfCYnyEs8QnhIalIBlhOubP/0pfu6TT20qymnHPcskC3INHkqtQArk1mZLEDabcn13UwNE@i@mLWjO0lb@zLg77PcOB1KL50F@ykvS1sXFRfLe1hPzWYEUhZ6pFl9MZ/NcMfdiOs8p5RenY6XYFF9M23y5nj1tt5pt8uTJh686r9L89IwOm6WAwPYf80qeT1Qr5GKnmEucVvALYVDCU/ISrtM@wT81v@zFzBqau32g2yRPEq0WfpuTL/HA9pJt@FNO8RwuxjOaDbEh7rRfvUo3Nc2fzohpmmOv14PbGZKUqqaPCTS129CIWASJtOibIhGuwmjaJ9M9YzCYHGgzc3LP3xVLYllUY4xp@@EXPwiu2gdPnxLylDx9@vJoDRtrZzIpQWhS8zR0fAAiTXZKqh2tkMBvfP3FDzbm2Ysnne2/@GQkGRv4eoyvr84fovlYKdza2Lh1504@n1VVlZmffPHJz@/t7eXvZgtPmoWdvCBvbP/5n21sqOq2Km20PU9pJ5unpx/yqpznxb/4XrLz5MkXPK@R@@8fv2oo@CjB44yUSAWvHFHAiM8y3AopFMjbXomXCQWuxIz@OonQ/WKDKI2d0v/85uMXCT/RUKUPXHj7iReJYjnBjGAAWy60nSUaiW0MVpwnZlK9Xgdj6X/@R4jfeA/goM9sGx6NQgirOEs0hDqNcploFMGgqCqk@/98/HEsh8DPgJXUaYsMr11giM0mny@p/E4bri16bXN4oI4gS1IYzvaHvuEQpXxbuY0WEyzwsuGF4x6tBH7l8PEuEZ8dZaBPyIjvNzaku9sCXOJYUhS1pSi3gf0Kt7bqdQH6Fdpsc7nCbTzsME17w4HjO8S4/cHSlfjgn@RaCab2wT/ldUT2Td1wnSyXKG7sPr/baEB5c43cViNDr6CR0fZWKvOOswu85mQ4cU0HP5dYe4Af/mjwclnls9ns7lEHopDpFFEoTKdiB0EQ9tXlBLvEDmEu2JwDR0aLcDWQE7RJ5M5ihdZFOPI82YQ20n6@PlziAK@//M9/@e2//Cb9fZve/xVPI7J7Zl/agkBn0FwacO1Wq3qjwTdc/qKF9gbQmFwtV8tSZ95KbTUb7SMQa9@9TBZySXJszbIdbDaklW41afwGTbYRJI/2RmLh3GAujbhb4MECUwd4B5giibCcsXJFWCPkSjguES6dEZpnjbaAo291oakUC22BxWruQuXwaqnCd9oJYXMGnEhtN9SC@pjsNthFhpsecTA3ObUYFiTIb2NRtoXPwtaIOyUaYbTGIsxnDRfkqcIlmk2pbdC@ohFmdHejulGuFquq1Gmsv2qLGHjRoIZhPPESZ4noqpGADkN8JiLKjLk9i9dEVC0kJGCyFPcN4aCugGlMp8F/zUWrK1dU@FpgUjs8qQF9qDlBHXR4WYHWttuJhPcduDbgR/9wRVZ8blCXwJkGuX5tkKqypeakwq3igYpd79XLFZqNDOWMQruREZFDCuKVMBz0JUTvdrsv9S5IJprW1XRN8bWJNtVmmt@ddKddX5/o@BVc8gTFu06ABjfnFJyyE2JFFBK5grKZuI1ly6kV/KAs6Cblcq6i5kpKrlTMlWS1XMiVK7lSPlcqAcBcSc1VKnlVzRVLuWI5VyzmihX8aC@EKUKYHEIoFXKVHJd41dwgR4y/TUkmvFqZN15PRcrR8KIGB29BcKYJEJxAc89yiX@Gq6GoCtmCzlGGB0iE1EhU@oMS7mvmxMtyJAHC3kX71Vbz1RaJ15YQ5BleYme3nRHm8yaYa7Xgv92IjDV6MRMUtT3PZLafNUAGetZoZgDkswCkKBAKVOw0SHubekWpBckF/ttt0h6Ad2bsDZBmBJqLF5CLzHZzu@7s01ukzVNoQzLbS1nf3aW0tguxGpvABtKZzKYgbDQBdjPooSAwUmRQRoDUJikQYC4ufsabJPNOsujsbm8Dr5lvzxvz5vZ8vr0N/236nAdvcJ1vX/vT1@JaE2bh30Y@1WpKjZbUCnhVG@yi1EAXUWqBoQFvCNfMqeU29o4o/Yjtf5l/Mbt4Ri6Y5bYIueYSW2QrgSf35BJbXOL560//N7xbrz/9Q5RkCfyMKpe4IIRLSFsVQt3oqwLi3EObPGSXDWa8Qyu6oEPjITra7GGjfixJz0VSFaiSnFLKxbSI3X/H6Xdwa6RInkNQCHYwMKARhbyX8Gq5yHcyykwliW2@WKLs9ueuXclk8l89VyulJNPBcW/fc8/zHsZyucgnBK6psiIolw12ICs7MfvnVl3/6ufWXVziskIQRynC8MIlgIwSkgS6I5dobI9woRl@bULAz4ad1T8Unu4J@85orPlUSccRPBAV6ocH9UqlgcqTsfmEtp2tu1vwVOB/sAGFIK0@BG316/oIBPNWP1dQW6irvquBzg6MTui@wN@Dl/gjJzr@jl7gj5y8xN@Rjz/ysIu/kxf42@vi72SEvzsv8PfwJf6eDvDX@lwup9T4Te2sN@3Bf/pyc7p5QXGVUSrKfHPKU5zVoMNrtD7nu7OqcaZZKV7dUfl0jVVxLl9Jg7b5OTayUg0@poALAQ3dr2n1Sq1bV1lY1numbCfyF01v8ZU6tiO0qqZxXCNXKTiuoBHTgwc4ZHIVxXGTP/nGJ58k6/WkkKRHiufBTehioC4NBFaImU/T/NDvCtUIkIHnJWu7yc816RhWodJuomcbPLhEnWwqm4psybqsdJUuGEwiu0QeykOlp1D1TjaIPJNnRB45Sg9MBvxkMJlyn8gDItuyDcHAF0x@R/bR1IfXAH59AOTCz8S1LV1F1gkkZKEsSz/1o3QwpnzZIe8OHc/PjltckyQJ/9wAPV1URFksmm08@L3JP3/ekrbaaqVMRCR7sdN83kq2@RaPx4KqlTzpzoyN1nMehBeZZ@hGF5LwPFD@awmp1ZKCalDztFrn807n4NHdTkfCXrRFjEZmNwM9wO5uHXqE4LWTaNR2WlXayYQdTULa3mk1cgKaixnoLlRwI/cNy7CzUuYzXgvA8G5sUAS0n58/B10pdY4a0/kZvM5DwwcteHSYLkW9pfMPWjErNcCFYSXpgxUQlgyQa9sF7YIsRET4g9L5z/U3/2X9Hz4laZJqttOpi/l2il5p/KXTF/OLefBspFOpwJLahh86gB2jXMwbaKSBLsDUTKXb6fmcucEzld5mABuQzHaDxl2Eg24nESVJk2WP1D/tG5IOrlayRp7z29uuftmqUW6QlyskwT@vEW0xIdFqTWXgHN3wzGLBJpvaJR29Tdd0/CDYZreptP/8e/Rc6p00DVTI12rKFmEWNa/WavnQVirXauXQsplKVa5fDXlHKYKKlc@n07UaWHZCsDJYIW6TvMqQOmnBs337NkukrF5ehjBz@WJGxomgWi1MqQDJGp6mMx4O4urhY3qmM3CLQoIgUyDBWHZKpofCI29P8lX@9u1U8NnPnb307dtqRb68jFzGY3BSlpw6nZ7pdjronru85Ds8nUSoFMAuly8vFbmSUZIk7bipR/jtRkgrJSjkltqgyVaAZ6v5Uho/z01zUNjeLuYbjWIeXIpliAiFYhwbmDmfrPGJC1oMpVxifIyvoTNJQIOGftS7mCdoTZJ8IZ0CHpgGOXOewJ@L7JL1WoVCupaX5cTFnGeBlUqFhU6TfDFVzlSCX30jTRogRLEfSoK5TH6rtLULgjb@vOmqCzlq7cKoK/P6hVHFL4LMa3rwZTzcZWrcvp2rAGrKcoLcneBe92yLC9hxHTomlMfg0eKSyQy5dZvDLbhuslrbpTWrlAskkawxRyEJbJ2UAceSulVQyogTzuzj3nEQKjiFdrobZINT6RsfXIV1xRvoCCpynPfRP9eDi/RIlwzwIgNUUYlJLHoRizB/@tT1KJDDrsA3stK4eEUuRnSxkflcIceoNEkeTHQTR8eePNjbPzjJqtsCSaj39vaz6vHTOwkFrYWFnXrn0H50sHf38VOI8OTBwd7xwbuH7x88fQLuHjlfXFEvEfYVUZ8RM62wn5MPuI/cl5phaMbEMDrnk8n5C/KRaXZMqFprAmVzBi7xjA4UaawtileDWzc97aOPNHdML/L6u19@/d1feP2733j9u19@/bvf/smn3/4y3N@H@xvs/Y0/qhTw@ZNPf/X3X//O74Ljf4X7T@H@wU8@/Y2P2U3tP4T7v8XcfhjcsXDs5gDW137y6Te/95NPv/6bcP92cP/m9ftXfrD6/vaX1t8Y75u/f3OYb/xHuP@AwQrDfuN3mBu@r4X/HRbu67/5@tf/E/v/efBD4@@@/vUf4iOw/PJv/vl/e/3Jf1HV8p//@9df@ubrL33y@ktfff2lf62@/o1/r8jxx@@//vYf//Wf/MFf/8m/of/v0@cfvM3/9W/@8l/973/1f/zVnwT3D@D@T2D6wV/9F2iuf/fH38X/N//47/70u/j/X3/v7/74W3/3tX9HDb/FDP/w23/Enj/65Ms/@tKv/eiTT9c8v3zj89O3cP/0n8Hl7fP5NnDeplyf1eXTnyk//xhsLFIBGgDK/cXXv/EVIN5fJ@T1l7@PK9vhXvP/vqrQMN9ntv8fGNTrZUYfGUxwf@v1l7@BKPpfAEXwj/D11ciy5MMsX11YAK3fWRHpF3/y6a99j9oSRrVBZ6awly6r5cwWKDRblUrQUweTVhDlK8vQIgBBSl9F7rPk91XkW6@/@/Hr7/3r19/9rdff/Rr2z0K@kt3LCsobZvwgYOEtwmHA4tuEw4AfQvqdDB20EzIfgm3jw0I5Z9t27cMPP@Q6lxJuodi9JB/Cj3wYXoR54RaLwCv0Q3fcc0HAvfn8eRuniWNuksKASyp7B164AAhSEtRbmR1JUZmXcSltslikBg65cq4Vy7rU729V4UfgUa1uXWSFnRYIeTTqnDPCIikB1A2JKFo2t5XTIKCUZ@FI1d6V85nSlqaB5ppBuBkq5myFwlchR6aZIMlpMJWM7hBoukWNU8JmA6bUe8pN6Ywz/EuElEmOEJv9axzJUImIXvgdn9BIDUG8cLaaGrkCJJNZzDVQaZAwQWyLudA5eJpuHrQPOoGXmYK2DQYcIAevOyDs1@sZjFhnWQQrK0yjTGhWMpk6lBtjszjZThlBTO9QKBCzTlFQn7KIGYTXCNGR4dCJ5iZTrt@FBOvTu@iQQeAU7PPn9Ua5Pm0guFcMO5lp5g7NEwKrZ6aNV2CvU5gQj0vcfQVZKdczmUYZE8RCsupBBRsrqUALR8uOE8CsDuCNq7B2dgm5xStlnk2zbCDCWGh8ZhahMSBGOXrOKyr/nM@rMg@BW5mtoGz0HxrpvUWxv0HTDZJkZceUNygw0nm@9TwISENCaoIgiiKBG1c87JBdssMxrGUyNDPwygRIpHRC6SJyIBRTXIbWOkMbwAdn@qFDoqr5GugbNYJOrs7hd5HoMhqZ25ziEqkLEsjGcvCxvzmnQZi8nOMuLrVgCdWmRubgVOQwBE2zvvWZL8wsYm1zc5NLNPgc/5hOGmckibinVboQDtoz1ZyqhC9WeHQ26KpAhsWHuHI7y1FzDYtJXn/8vUReLiW4zST9sCphCZFbGXbv7m6RW4BW@o65Tel6MyGTc/JOgqFxO5PhVUi04YBti6IwQ6Fxz0iijn9wT1ByIwnyRHNNL8tlKaPMwkusJ9CbPH78OMgvdXhW5zLQDtWcgnacMJxMJhDd6OHkfDYrilkxmw3eIn1TBzEwiNQ3eIubiHoS1/CUUhm/qGjrQ8QL9@rVK6ANDnFRPcShUGokdTVfpp6EksEUV4JpoyzHdphb1ixccKrmKxwbnyBKMU9IilIEXGmCKytTQONpji3PYuQVXqmkWgYlGkNCjYkpCMbAFBXkVGwJK91LQgqlJSvkLG7FUUc29o2rBqK1oyx/qXIhHXruPyb7jx8@PHh0Mm63CWfQL3ganbHr6IbnpdBv79FdRr5qpZhONJtY9pOqipyTO6jKSMaZw7tHh8dVwjAWVF2KlqNGJ9wDvFQULjEef7CdcHH83TV4/GCNwx/js7pARUqtAFdPJxpcQjdQDQM6xT/cNXJkDJB8H3qDO86UpOQsz2eVIirJaZw/huz8vDMheCAd2wUP3AGX@YlQXsx540KIzUChQ4McqRwzCAo1kFylHBpKzKCUihjgMfuyU45rHB@cAOSTx0RRZZEcOV0TMtX4kExFQoAHHDkjw8kKcxobOdKJOXIwhFW3DHvgDzfxa5l8S@ZjCNpsyln8qbkcPJV8MasUSu2NDetCQDgtSjIXuIhxDtYLAXHyDlyEe4cj74ATXMKccM7YsEkwuH/4uMaIF/dXkhTk/th3eaUAfCHN4ZxFAI8bx68aYh0a2vLsH5fY@OIXfdJoHDy6Kxzew7GI6ZCESyAFsycORUo5vYlrUN8BIT3zfRPXfos90xtb2gxaMSBsqwEY8XFqNjGfz/sA8/AeURsqtbK4PXzOderSBfN8qnEEOHSfS9wOh1@40u1qtf5KyZcgb9Xqq5yqcuDAbYGwYfY3gNzocpYtif14u55X5IwSTIfYJM3zfM2DTOVyZWmLSyg8D69cLsfRFkS4qsERusjplVyvCwGTzyt0jROHx3Rr07oaXUHY6a1F2JzMwqIPeJCB7xI59Csxv8AW9gtQFFz1S7/bWAtYinz7dg4HoXJ5OSo7oaghc6jTzVw@RyvpnmH7SGcEfduJfCmYT4NythOcZfikVwdzooUFp@myVdT47WyPTCBkMQ8s8byqKnRBczWv5hM8wdDIKHNlmUs0E8ADuGa7Wf///tducu3pv9w/oKXZrHNTYKXxO3DGMPRNln4c99B5vPg/fjyKW2/8jx47Dx87Iwf@0GU@RE5fW/xrtSXrzf@AxSKXrYEkzfnGFMgOfnm5ANZ/@PbHf//r//nv/@1XRbwCW@TwD9/@FnP/7V/F57e@/fff@oW//9a/pS6/8ve//W8Cr3/47d8jd4EXzF5qSKL4YfNP/wi/c/7Jd/BT52CN/z/9D4HXJ99aOOKH0L9z7f8t8je/8n/@7Xe@@tc/@Phvv/WDv/2tP/7Rx19Xy8qPPv6lv/2tH/z1n36NgP3HP/zKjz7@2t/80ic/@vgXIVz8/@MffjX0@lLkCGZwuf4Hd4DL/Yu5kCPiigA6yb0dHBTYoKvUm0ol3z4AptIk7e3wDMEGhN72gs@bA5ep81jVkm8yN77hGVZfxLXfdX573MjJKr8dHETcIO8bNjLtIH6jV@85Ov2ocK0nmvhxZ9wNxOLl83zNsfG4sHo0b0xS6YtB/Zzu8q0Z9YGIB1O4tmZB9K7Tm4mePwOZTHcsx60nQWtNglj7vulYlF7AvNdzbBQZ7boBWg2O1e/kcvkqlE8cO@MdtVASiNBUZJDz8FbK2R50PO4OdHhVNbth7JRK1Z6oW4bm7hSqBfTWo/n/nYJcHYgfPnxw3/fHRyCiGJ6/k69ABDzcCY9h2SlXCwVowzyfadIU2/i1VNajCxsb0AEaWk@ANy4P8AS13K7S9Ov1ZHInp6iCUs3JZS4o7AJhds0W8kpxR676cTSSA8u0HTfLc/hRx6gWsAKHSiMv57cleIOmLuFaBZBfGmTPGBjYAdCaU7alMdIEGCGoBsYuGAvbUheMJhgr25IJxkkjp8jb0gSMeiOvgKvOqARrg5i9OqSJJctgtrNILtmhchF06FXbsY05V81qWfOC1ly13@/Pty4yCwunXQjMBnU6F7Rs9yKy1oRYuCqZZAVz4QkuWh9I5CJYmlHl1UKZrzVrC3upyNfac253ZPRMDT/I25IvrscqgqTFoCYgoRbh5lXXcfxq1@g7rrEImFOKYUCWoesB8vw8Sq4lY4oX15MrxgJNLxbYi7DWtRz9NEiJfpluVVr5Aj/n9AAdrtGbs4Sy1WzoyKJS4sDKwmpLPHvGJbaO3s81GkCdF/mSmi/kC2quWCyUVJAqK/lioQzEIRflgqoCi8hXypXSHNqmJL1K0E9bkf2LsM1W6eHmKa3Kjvxrtkn61SPTuijnBMZkUukaSCGJV1zi1tH7aqOxfjAsBRL6@6rQqOcKFTDl0KTmqKyiqoKaE3KKoOTw/waDiv@3D6/CX8UnxMqp3AkeiPIIhGPQC2zyAM908B1y4jh0l9EdQ18TYn@o0cNX9l3H8/4RYe5o9inzumuy0zcjr/safgLKG5n@cE2Ip@ORaXu4VemfC8LBqAsZRJ7OAtyBh2s5zqoAJfL0CTyODt@9fxK9V5f6YXSeNSCHHWgNMU4O9vbvc0Vy5/Gju1dehQBcgTw4uHcSWUvMN4xaiED8/MGDB1etwSv/@OlRf@K4eHP3Hj/NLx6RE27O4vJwLQeKnCmQ4IFWFJlQAyAboIuHBoXDfWG38xVyOzAWigujjMYP2M4z04u2jrHNi1XuJNyOphFk9F2D4CdzjB4d8qTHuwXDBUqpwnFjYjvnpCSTnmNZGn6hur8BjkPNI13DQO3Xoh9Yx6TPHdfqnZs9YwNETUijouDXgDET3H0AMproQ0wAlA88FLSH347Gyf@uNTHIBL/bvsYRXuiERtccDEGeOHfCAFxX0wjcn/WC@Eb88m928Fka1O2aj3U9OJfg9h7jsEYlwfP7PH9f87Waa5SekQYKSsNsOZvj/QI/wEliy/N7za0J6E4bG/kyUVvyvkzXUM20uiLVunWiFC8bO3lnFzUr1Nm3OkaiPKhXvUJR2cE@uC5ndhOOd98o13hes7PAMrNVD4cr7tFPcx/Y5jMyFTs46tqq2Wy8w6PUVf2b73z/x3/2rddf@cHrP/y3KOaRu46ra7icGRVcQtXVQM8V6fiKWikXypWcWs6WK@V8QSkWCllFzSqlcqkCmZOVslIsFypKtpyvgHyWr4BvoVIKtGRJ2iJ7Fg6LZZkmLG1VAbyt4ydxt@lQjThscAm2lIS8TGlpktAi@4TwBsThyZ49MCyAgSNsPt0LuWXWod8mikxyJQKQNaKTxL17@/K9ezx/By24wG5f5vkeWgplWS7d4XmD@uyXUQTlHRanjOe88T6zyPIdqMIJA4BHm/P8EC0HRZw44XkTLft79@5hOn20qBgfgp0yH2axQksJgtloAbWdAngRQYNgeyydPM3oAVowSfS5x3z2wY/n3w2zgz5HLBgDcD8s6d4ezx8yy94e@uzTYhdYRj@Plj168bwLFmhfPD8Aw8CFls3zXTBiK@N5HUz6TAM3/Awxnopt@xrPzxh6EEE8P6WhNf2U5zuhOybzfpCbAmK3Si0KK/UutVTwx/NqmGkMlossOZ7PR5Y8lO3@/fe1od8zBuyaueytQ0nv389p5nRycK/77rvdwaDrzvYO3j1Cr/39@yDRzCZud9ANInY7cDkQa/@@qp2OZlcvKPVhp1PVrJVen@908pp9xasz6xiYQ4j1AnIWXANMaNTZB6/9@51dbdXSIAqwgwxmBO8uXndG8L6jdZlXeFEv@p52u3wNmgFoK60UhwoWru7B5nkKDNvOjjTddWpon9aJTFdVz5pFuV2jHmQEGpJcm6N/P4VPDUex0xez5rQut@vTeilYoNtP8a2pWjD57MZoR6kUqhvajqLmM9MqbuN2@kmSFJQdklJub70kqUfpHRX0pA2@tbMj8E2lvVMsPUPOVsXHjqqUq3lZJWlmzZWqEEdOyoTgI90stXdKheoicqmU0SS1WiqB7Af48UGC6OK4cYekUueGdppOY9bpwCOUhxaczGihzVo/Nc1O6yyTZJauTetKjR0lS@Qr0FKpHp5PPtHxHAvCgA4A4BQUJVxWluKVSpmHPEhSKg3MaD6fM@Rc5OXy/OLCu7hozSNWKYFpMfT7wRdOTk9OPgRuBSLJjI2YNYJB0yfsM@C1wPru/X3x8HFow6PHxXsoHTuuuI88bsmHicmh0wnoSuJ96NdBTw7dII7vOpZ4QFdhg4gdeoTnf4jB8aDiyf0lOMdD55ylDJG8GkpxGm6gx5PZzR7R6g0waT2SorkiWvqcShSdRqPeqY@M0difQRHDWJ8n9NjyBZhDj@WdfikCv6NNo1/0XWcUeHTq8hx6vWliKghkDwS8iZsFiJ06EZTnI6f3XM3otR4ezX6nfgfB1Drw7oKmb7iu4/KgqPK1/o5dn9ie1jeeGC6eCnD4eBMkHTxUI9UnRnqTtA4w9D4qVnOh4RJ7kcdHk1FKExrd9LITTjREDoim1BfC4l/gQDvknOfntX6dpJ5B0BdgdzdJqifeSe/ka4CxO6STBif5ef95n6ikmK9RPSiFsKAJUkwhBrR0vfF5ENAY6FNSrUJugio/BaiYGACG2qA@Wnpszmt63SIpgUzTFEf52qDexOiX@NgWQLoQhOZlG@cJPkDl4MUEOs8GNPfaLKHVvUmXfqyDyF1FlYu1KbgppXxtCPWtPZvW3Pp44ho1C6zBzAKhJdZqgFtAIYB5eZl6/ZWP09tCoc7cahTUJQotHbFTn9ZsPGYRKKWeq4NHppmXs4UyyDOFUhZECLWYVYrZXDafFUroCvJDtpAFR9DDQDJKWSmeED4rT2VRySqGkk3Jz83e83T2NCUDHijy0lnfObAnI4IuUGVIrdQOby2dUbcART2HaNsCJV5gMjUsF@B@SMZmdkghHRmaxSKkBZLbSlmbKQy0eTIZHzTb1erBdPwF8EoJL3aKmZKceZlO11Ib6bpnvKCzMHdMIBANkIuciRZ/vAE0Hcy@EG8yakKtg0kpqdVms4tlLcnZnJyDYpqdy8E23@DbWXmjqECdzekgu0IYZ4nPN4DkxC3cxh1UFCwD6lCpqDVOxGH@BLnjTugESK6sChWpsFWQ2aQDA8GNAxaJuCWpVriHI5lKJktqMrnQqtPJGk7vbvCL@Taqa9OFt6kksGySvK0Wijs8CIB8la@oPARbcFzMJZHDnG@Rfc3wNBcnZjgcqyB50NUvuPnFfLvBTUXuYGRappYltqnjV69M/VTkUJTNkq45IH3Nx7YscntQ2sOqyB2DomdQU/MATz4nLD49DwOjtQOAVTpr5Q9nQwO0IZGb0Uk8X7zuCrVE8B0mtRyCfI47xuMUttVn@Cs9e7j3GH/3dhO4W4Lsfg78KuBefvbw6eOnj@/RLfOLPa2f5drliES3RID8XkvU6CA6rneAZJhw//bXLs5qE2kDd4WTjCiIDXrewC5LpRWcfCNtEPJZ92xkthvP2LuFmwIBNEePXW6SNl1LbZiop5P3NRAod0gSqlxzR01VzbWbagnEEui6mjILqqpKDXLRSdAtrg2g7@kFZHo708BTBT5PZjMtI4RFv00ag8ymrM4SZx2@WMnRLfCdhiKfko3k7S38nrBAEmenGw11K5N8Us1lkneTuXziLNXabGSUWVIiWxl11seVYbjCSEpCONXYupXbSj7NVMuDbFXJ4FOFZzVJhI3Ebie7m654HKVkklhC8EZlr743ONoL5jjI3n6jrM6C0xASzzp8uRRksbUJKFMzz3aX4jdAFnqGM6JX6o38DNcuLhVP1pKJiyRJJOfJeTPZ5hK79NwGlZ3bQBLRyQ24vitYTZDLF0k6QdKBrVRJeKk0XV0RTOd/LrmbSOKsOfG8V0DUtC5o0w53wX/@uQqMJmE7oYMz8XFAF0SpQgHnhBPS87H3RbWce3j42L7r3jO4RGvjcsPB@X5S4xlInryy3/sCIWOosSRp1RPTej6YVFUaDUHZVvG8qxKpghDQV4qCfNlg3KxBPYoq@Lz@ym/mp9tlsKuyAnZVLWTURkPZAjE0MX796R/67oxcHLy/94AkcYr2x3/2PbX04z/7Pbr4PDmn07ZqrpSAkGhUiqXExcX44gKEwDnzKyTaiWsL8tqAJknRKqUtEWhBKmtg6EiJYNNbSikp6YQnJIKtB8WCkEopkpreypXlNPhcBmcKpVS5DNZw8QR14osFPp04ODILqrK7vQMl28nl1doGVKsSHcdBot@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@RBriBaN3L69yFW9bvbShJYI4Z@aYxywpfVgr84rAAs1@VvAUkGkymSwst9ZJjvAeIZmF6hOYCcR1mJRCY/WOcfB/62JFinySlVRjxoWIKgv1ip0QBlERrSzOtTJdp0oailNoszrkHedZoqe@hMNT7Smt0T1w9BzDjn8aSL8EBAwq5P4IHhAt3cN63J0GSHcI6CETejhmP5QY8wg@Ag4yCwQHZneoR/GjmJBUUyLhu6bLqjCdAFeeBxeKqekMdri@ECaD7q5Ts0T3OJWSOOLxsLQBN4aHs8WpLNBxVfdgQr1xo5Nz3PzkTXhJkOgCOBRkMAjxzdYtif2OX6dK6gbGjmeIyglaDpI@Zhjej4d/eQ3jYsr2bquoZ2GuMkSYyASfdQjaoWkKKHZuFbDjsClaSSa4S5oUIjjrmWMIEvHhkH3v3tVSRqA4Dfp4vS39NAEuhreM6H7sT0p@Lq6dG6emtIJnsQsOH3cJk@BAxSQFbH5sbVwoGxOrB6xHOeUWOapweY2UvGz8fCDB8UsKD9ZwOziBsRWUexVc1kcCFOyLBTcJXiVmLGcjcXdSM3S1985ZSPVwRq9pD2Y6eKX0880O4Zfel1ywWCKN/M4ehRgnaDykAK7GLFcaJnsVK0kHquVTIuA@14qzdH69SAKxhRxzmyc4hN8WvTGlulTIzd2jTOCgyEc9jHANPVOkAVsxVDad2gHQNsetCw8ns93q1BzGciJ20vp0PQCBm@TWySnchgQUsagLAMAA6u@vgwd/CAqlsPze1AxIp0oQr4CrXPUAz88/isgP4wfUjea6WGJC/ImGwE47HRoWnXCmkVoKcQs2DqQnmnRN8CzCDlckZONFJ8BsBk@zTPQUfyr0Rm1c5SXVMl1SFmCEAJUAxQqKmjIcvB82tjntXC9yB0NuDOeoI5UD0R/fn4u0pMoJ64pGh5@cspzbM2SxgMTxGFH8o3ROPgor4nfWQ/gLkwC@6KcOB6Od6Yo1NYrt2fszXF9rx4sbU0l@14SO8cz/KLSYHSG@hVkuO9Rgrpn0q@u6algpS2jP7WdvQjpr4r0J5STcwRCCIKZZmdZPQvAsl39NNs/79UCjzPaIAE41KIROuL5sG5oGXmhyRz3oxCOj3w08upap3RRAUDi2YzBImlWwjDkLLQG9rGJK@Jt45zsua42S1H/NIZGAk7NqNhDZtDtUx8wQjdDLthhpea0OWsvRZ9G0aFTixYPASNPYc91I1B2ci36T5n/FPynzH@6SDRMtjltM5EMneZYHKR6XNofhkQwszDMnJ3yuvChkEEOJwoDgSFnS264BFiv09ghvpkN6rEeEgbQxBgQbqSk5rNWs9W2PeN8q52RBkDsPEUE1DiAbrYpTs97kRmxb51ZY8dbcoLug4o3Qb7RSR8G1MBoBcsYVRAlDIYvE0/mHIyCRU1MIAgKDBBQDgNPFA32/JSZrkVHJVNPIJwmv8Axy1gzyEybSl@BV@AG4hJDPUNsHFA7BgjdoyJBNsGHhC2HfWAw5A4fuA6ECcMK9JtowCJnJNlOAiavNBXGa2q0kmK5EoQwm4B2FFfrV4sS@kNVNK94xYo5D@o/nv2Nz5z9PrSL1bmnBMs6jBoXbyq4jh9EiKC5UKySRj1Wr5ADaUuzDBd6rgMmnwa9NSSzJYVqBksHi@Cd/7/tff1@2kiy6N/RU3RwMiBbfDm2k8HGs9jghF3H5ABOJhd7WBkEZgYQg7ANk/H5nYe473Ff5bzGfYp766Nbaglhk2Q@zu5vzp6JhdRdXV1d3V1VXVU9mHWuU9rgd0weH0qykBgnCj4rLIpF6OKiyNOS54UiKRPcr@bJagvFCLI@LyAAIxdbzZHV5nq1ebHIC4eYr6h2pyE5JyTnXIVLz1cgeSmrgfZUVdsLDs8lSKcYYZAAeHneRkEMmiSEZ9866Mbx481oglqVajNYc4gLJA@hiI181rmMbb2lIa0tWhEAyIhLALp893DBiC54@bT/y1@jmJRqjeJfkg14rQAGoyV432AdyGcy0oFB4E9s0T4Aczex1TISeToqwP/l@L@EpV6q//LLL3Phkvnwy5wV@d/v8vISKatNUE36yOd2cEE2AkuFbrJ464I2GNghNKcJ7RUeFoXfwQIwpmKswY0QSooUtwfNC2Rf4CnO7IEfSYoKVk5YoqQ@xguNlTj3KMMzNSIoz9cd6BkX44S5ryWZV1aGYGMU4qR6WhGbFEzSI8FZCc2JaYKlFEbj6WD8EAJ0ukeSN04islo89wrwH@BgKZBAJrJfpIg25qO4EUWubnotStYkJwLxqUjldWwQwR4ox2M8XrcSzz2RsL6BiiYybqV2YhrhbO3ymCRUH5DzJuMU1LIS6UyCqsI7WFrxnRkGwaOJ7xXCgDLKpkoRQ4UCr9XK0HUizhy6Mu47pJjZ2fyr3N63BvVubM2sUevbS2uzU0wIWILs8ci7md51f@q717c9MRSTH6/mncUvPwuxu4OBsWL7Gw5xzO8VsxSS9VJgzOy3OcqzLxH8joI4MU92Rpm0k4Iy7HM4wFNB2f4F@SoUUCaMcKnYHCkuRKPCrDhq7V0Wx7AIj1rjy300a8y2irOt/FYKX3yTNzGfD9ZMdVqzS6DLvTaLNo3XNmg1eNOfKF15dPgJe5oRMhfMYIf08BSWDi/w@pfhAAR9YqY7Ukhl/B0oK8CwAUT9@l2j2kPNnspb@CTVe6iUETWEfDdAocT/4OFlYR7tsHjEOsO08QASj7tAwqCs7bDLvthmpd0R2CMsBbt2X0cCRxzNMTj9/VzwGUPmxTe4q9QXNI7hTa0CFVc89YedumAY/3Ez6Px0/Fps53Iv87kXeY1keD0nIpjLvNgJtisgkvqwjW4@u/kdwzh2Jwv224PNHGHtpBGgJU5ROX4Peplz64zHjlEaDtnBz8PrC5zprdPNGEbd6ZLv6NUNUQTVuBskF2i17s20wznv6X7vBfIFXshBWfJh8uNfdEwcgarTk/eRWQZaQUAhGw1mbCtxbwd4t4Rv@em5w6F7hwTroNGF6YGVRg7sccamKcIoIbEULqTvj268GU5ptBojQPsKb8/s@GQYw@bXgZEhE4YxBFBkuNMaG3cjmEB7naGNqlYmDgFoSKOAQgC61r3pOA/iYBASn4mDkB1TURm2GpmsOzVcmisjG1VbuqdeEZhGhappuMMAN99UG6JRO2l@KNUrAp7f1Wvvq@VKWRx9FM03FXFce/eRvHLFm9ppuVJvCAwWPa6dNevVo/NmDV4kSg2omaAPRunso6h8/65eaTRErS6qb9@dVgEagK@XzprVSsMS1bPj0/Ny9ey1JQCCOKs1xWn1bbUJxZo1i1pV1YygnqidiLeV@vEb@Fk6qp5Wmx@pxZNq8wwbO4HWSuJdqd6sHp@fluri3Xn9Xa1REdgxo1xtHJ@Wqm8r5Qy0D22KyvvKWVM03pROTyMdrX04q9QR@VAvjyqAZekItkdsifpZrtYrx03sUPB0DMQDBE8t0XhXOa7iQ@X7CnSnVP9oSaCNyn@cQyH4KMqlt6XX0Dkj9QhVYFyOz@sVPIlCSjTOjxrNavO8WRGva7Uy0bpRqb@vHlca@8I4rTWIYOeNigVtNEvUNMAAasF3eD46b1SJbtWzZqVeP3/XrNbOTBjkDxW8@uO4BFXLRODaGfcWiFSrf0SoSAcaAEt8eFOB93WkKVGrhFRoANWOm3oxaBCI2NS7Kc4qr0@rrytnxxX8XEMwH6qNigkDVm1gAYCJ7X4oQaPn1GscJ8CLH4FZDcW5Fg2nqJ6IUvl9FTGXpYEDGlXJLUS24zeS5hl0sNUEtAHeAOfYI11o6y2/unXQKWxZ2ouX//zzp@NauSIS6twwEXw4h13nVeRgSv8GO43/EX6GDgC6ztVNv433rqDE7ldjoWrk9S3MlWBilPaF8cBZtZTdqMLGRrv9vtQu1V832m3TWqdmCI3HalAaUBDWHihlyj5iWBna0FCoLBSY7gchQh1@g@Jgz5lagh2RqSRT/xvaXPEyeFNks11HVkNTCAJWYinswVN3JABYF5dGssJiXHnQJEk99Hsg2YEqphT4TKcNr7HnXMj14J/xr8EP3hy0F7A6syidzfadGaMBCqpqhhshAxP9I@07oH2RJO85zk/9VE5vzhl3zQxeUoQekrIOlZ05w2E/ZT5S/crpR6qno/UJWTRqqvy5HkcXsHaBjMnnYJJkQo5LZko9S@E/7Rn9MRU2bEFDQwk1RSZ4qRClvuHqrdwlkpUNhSBR8yCjzPe29H31Ayq5ue2d/cj7N/57nlvoNIj@pbDhtajeJf15c8kFYIKRZRNIMpD2xmxWqwNiGQmUfuE7KHiNhfiSJdyrrx3a14EkIMje2EO9TdyNp4O5jj2sw6/rpbdH5ycnsHQitjuvdl/u7Rv@Ieb3Fv/9iO2Qhyed4U5gHwc5jT5ps@QYBB@aKZo7fsD@xMDZLBbEaA41aPQSrWb@TUYsJHB2CZKlDrC7HiZZGKMZJOGM6fYlMmc@NRS/xs5MyQCpUFdN7M3InpOIb4OsRDwgD03xGnUYtTn@g7D96a@muN8hyUCSxcjnFTjXeMLrXgIr0Ulbz70Z8zEIFskkFB/zobhPA7yaSeQL8hiRfkne1kYRBFscaJyvNOxUE5B4GsVCSD2UvLuhiXdktZXKJZ3FwpvvJb/B40fpLkDOA7Y3K80aQMYTvybqwIGiKzvdkpAvMboOj6hVSwcCLQimRIrmnlRVfTOrNhsIFQxvRetUGPC@b5WNNomKcPJvSdC3mVPRFIpw9iXHyt/AuXHdkVD2lTVW/lY2PsGwfJMxU@3Ob8NQRT76VkFFzhCZvooeBP9PpEkM/APQOAF6QC3NpWItShJUphWor0SUwZ0yYmiWk4Ca@quPAZh7fWCu/Y5Jy9CcXAmQBHJ0FurFR3Ii6aViCIBMbqJngTZ/u65D9x/Dzgyq098SpqyONphxZzRJCblXqK1iCW5679IisctSdhv8YQqTDLNCa/AUqoq/seJ2RbMeVKaIKi@eewkGZypranYTzzOCCU9cihTJq8kecFZOzjK1DsiDK23D6frnTyCW3q@0CG4KzeEotPZLq5oiFIA@RHyW@0lhhq7oDF3Pifiv8JUATfIpQO99S96fJx0A0NMAXZwQzvOukFfTObM73CCGDJ0cHwJoIvWcfC@wET6WCAQHtdyaGSAtbat3PvZzwv5Ow/58zDEm9LMgVIkM@5hIDMd4tyDwDF0VLN7aC0B5uF63mcWymw3XEncORfKwWULWx6jLjutOQXS0sd@AozVYmBnxQRodnLF3M5XeILCfDabSIqGEfmhmRjd9Ey1wm@HYDULNG4DcMEObC/IHdWnk2GPpIDKYp/dECphX8eghsjC5tcy38iJ1EHw5AJqQkxcR8UDsYeoyKsUElQ5YDlFw4PnKBcwSl9s5ELlg@t25059w70cRaNx1ur6flwYSXqhBqo7JY6Yz465PXI8sGjAUaAHxKZFnQ9qV3fnpDiVv2KNfSnYCAR1fJQJfI/QEo558fjs@k0qo2FDAuLJ1YL69NAwmUmlbOlr5rlf57V1CJU7hul@pjJHvVdgkLhIXY39JKcgLQJ8r0RGfeN30nz7iE18A5xSfezh74A3az6UIigijzIo22@V1jvDD84oPA2fa1W2iIMl07Qma30j1ccfEi8p0KJ0oOvbMcxagAXSyg3mWYLRTf3evx@1jd2j3B@7ABj0NwyvmvOLh44IeccD6U/fOo4BiTkikFeougmeyhstDbfwtPXbwZ3DQ6c2cSUo/AplNFyVMtoBaDB3j41mrv18Rf0@iJ85@nZ3doJJfR17yfeNdg266v7Lui3xcZT4tQABygTuMnM7QMbmDPo9F1ZI7SWnHHarA1UMFNByvRFrY2uf7lRh/CySiA94QxgqZpSMPvROoma3EuNWdW13y6Ji6M1i3yg7GrXopem3ZmCwTVpHv8BSiIPKvclpVykTZnaNXBz4sVpN7@@WfjD0g8BXo51/EcUscI9AS15OzAdZkUiakzxbgQu7MA1qjaSWGVWzQh11oGALankehhj8vVlGDThVBKJJOC0tciTMyBYoP5r1ItWHJaS/omuykSJrkKIAiSIkud1nFsI7OrLp/jd4OHnFzmF0GF6ZjCTmlIb2KVB2gEibaC8Gc3Ogos4fq4zNme3vdUYsQsCgJGMJBy0CZSijJBT2x@UriGR1ruVNYjBMR6slTyaQ3cyfJNam3cu2IPeeOo3XHXEWkTxFmK8Jmudkl0hYX@LjYN6L4RJgmTDE6xQYeQvWVnn02jxJxXmzjfCu2F4/QYRXNgjNZf1Pxx7vLcx83xVsMLVUbjT@lCHd0@dr337fa0PH26hVEwmT1qk0rRhuXjPaCHzVQETL5VFqfQsR9EvcIPbpAOWy3C7TTx2clUaMH8MqBTH0KuQwhPdEN3h45uC5NehnoSMpU51P@IuULnHNrQUd5@fQVumziBwaIUrGTDuxQbMENBivCRxRr0Uu10S0wjysRPB2yz67yfJKI@gSjGAdp3GH33lZ7kc5f7jOkuQ8JtAq@q/sBSPIVFmu15wRliRQwxWNI4fdoaW26Xr9XX9sXKAcQuDZ99m7wCB6kKewMXg7fuYZ/9E/tOcrAQVOyZmhGhSdCm5YGmAugpfSHDqurKP0Npszx8JCS0wgUCH6dwj9bsgY6R@/lfGpjlXl3gUVMSW6ebSamRKMqAUPxbyS/nIos6pLiCgAcecMZzI88QEAnMcIeDwWGTm8W4rwQonKMoGIxj9MSXpKPWeBDEvMdiSoL7OxqJXJxJb7VYaRjgYBgEV8mQARklvgiARTY6GJx0Uq8jO9PUAIEYsX7THEYCjkqYRr6I8cEpHR5OTNYUVp5YeUkB9PHnV0z9NHnb/r6bU77mot@Bfr4GLbS@ejXV7nQ11Cz29vhqqGaQA9TbzX0EUhh6gj7q8LX/Z9BLoGaA7mScA80JSMkZUjfL0xnCFom6G2ZHz1xgCaOQyVjKHh0GJfOk6qo1K82B6yFXNwfdmcXSToyQE/4r@6titlQmMjIi@TFmBzt2bjLCiFJrAnc6rFbqOmSNwUaTsjjBPRbpdO6PfG@eXKiK8HiaqEcjUbOdDeXyyETX@mhBMpvC01JAzcbLp3t3QyH2cnd36fvr7K09mMm6qHnFpQG7cCQwKTwMu60z3E2iAMUxdJpIPDIvXVQ17/p9fSAFjyhxMGDYeOS7CvWFbQBDXynl/dNDrA/CTbYf2IHsX//FP7su7NZ0JRQ1DEU1AbqXdwm1OkZkAdf9ND3yz@pImC4MCtvJti3zOLhJ9xBME6MBoucQU00C0n2T7xxhkPXEh8wJdnTBFlUIhVOTvQKOS6CJ4xIFHQxGgKHWcK5HQyD8ykPi@i8juDUxqSidpSXPUYa1J1@ZT5JJVo/JGBbgS5vYTe30NvXEol@wpSu92uAZT4EtNcqPbInqQ7RKVoYtno5g4MnwOhF3orVfUJFTLKJSZo9XhqJGo9u5kd3ME5B102SBVRkAA0v9WRFcZ@4iYt5voc0zDEMiRPdF7dWjfv9r1sav25ZvJ31euutihRUwQP7WSsix5V93YJIZwA0A@X0A3pidOU/0jCtTyKBUCzgYOjT8rqDFdpYwTCed4o/36VKpZJ4NtnaEqXSETxgop@jkijji6MjUcYsKvj7m@L27u4@r7ll8xO8PFIv78URwOCraTvX0zL8hG9FDHCD7Z60yGfZ4jNr/1m7eHC472VbpaPLbLYPT3w7U7Ykf@C1Tdkj@tH6wS@UyWSyzzqfnn1zv4@/W@XL5LOr1rPJZbK/j1wGZCjdzNzqLG0H7qOZ6ZWxwbuA9pb8SJWe7WEqV1lVqPQII3v6E6wuBbHR8bIb8q3Hcbi0xm50HO29M8ZEKKDCqxCOqCpvYIj8yF6gOR5Gp@OgAx7sN5THlfxAuT6frSjD/djVCvinKhuEgJRZbx0AjSccC@gkN4zxA@nB2HPGaAG/JZmXu2cYNvwdzNqSf7M/yPsUNi9SYjMnNi2xmUjQH7xbYfPCfJYd4I0dXMy/dSE4WkA3Q@ENSNAj/YEiFyPkNoxnFACJkFQ4NBUe34yu0PistD8Mn5Th617feEJXSLKJhA6ZsMrGp2fjexiWT1DiPmE8oXDGPOb@YEGhLbUYakw7UfHHF0Ug22NHgKDlEROk4EKTeNIHlfnML6veyLE2KDaTACNZ669PaN7jC9iLnlFMZz6iS2HQKAU/8lvcG/c5eJfQxi/cfoAAHaiwOpmjsJHkRhLPOihtv99L6qagGE@9f5L52Ndh4cywYtD8fwqNCejTE51wz8b0js4x6SPTPzHwj1e0phJclqLt@WTG0KqMboazwWQoz7yIRDhyfmv3PJNwRAkQw@EI6sLyDCNDAWY@uHMoDFkfFg49Xoiui13nmSDzreJ0MDN8cqQRIftDCub2r5G5bWYHiIliB@YBQsp35evZg6GHJJ@pxK19e3qFuRYoSbMYzPjcjOx5mFcngrHb85HOEGRyOQ/mM3RlYzK1@yPbEhtnbnNqL6qwbYHkM@tkTOjhODkjJHDyyabjuqcQ5h7JISGK@F0hzyGM3h4uZLA5jy2OBg0GDamaCjJBA06CEDsRJZ1fQ2MVoWPA1Z8xCDrKS4u3fxopl1haedHTSEIKugD/0DRbmjqGakGfO/7ESRiMqj8zFS/ISje40Y7o4BdWcszqrdqmmo48HxSwXGL7uDv1nbEd2pwmQ8PgxCTPsvuC90Wcz5TYg72R5E1A@Zf5IH8AYgVy5A@hBDcy04XbY5nNeJJKPbnwZHD8hr6PoPCc8X3xszayqjwrp3DwESXlOx8PeLGM7FADpj0wYUZUyfMfIPSGdh/wW9zZC2TFi43Ud0@zZuuHi/HlZupi/OvFLyZhIpdktcumxYY8zFYrlpwrsDNmrdBP5ZXmCb7FXlyMwwUuxuTWxaf3kgSASDbV@iF7@WsWELrYMM3N7MUGEyQ0ZIhJ9uH2sgg@u4TmRhiL7IbxxNw01eCnvsubAvZW@otjyC9M/gtYKKWSzPSg50x7AIpigOgaAlTssq@2czvb@R3QhPrOPD11bnC/TXs3V84cRAkP1VnYei5@CXFDiBD3c8/eh5dz6OegP8Zc0DSinkxoIZdQOc2pHcNnK6iTYZ6A8kDlFJIAQ1xMv4yNh4@o8FsCWE6VpYwW7DqocV8K90/PHWE7tofrWjQ6hDkSvQzYR4RMqGmELBlvJYeaarokKdgsI46vHRhkBALDm93QdouxO05LYc3MJPdRiMaomSHm9o3O0aUpGpqhz6QwlXwq8offvfzv/137eWO2cbid/TCFv7ONnzf2Xm3wIzzArxfq1@3G4cYBFtu731hkQQeGx5f//X@g/uHfAQ5@WRzAP4e7CtbeYuMwXaQqv24c7sFDfnsb2v2///Vf0IdnrLFhZptnbUsQYvuKIsf2mHgXvosq9pLV0mSwrORxYUEY7GEIujn8QMeo@farHJnpNqRXxS26/wx6M98fRW7x5Jg1I1chtmQofwqQjLhCERtIM0jlQtETmu@GcttA5g3QFP98ntnzQAP4p3Tn8Jv0XTeee@gy9IzVIhjAFLcI@jw/HOa@S/juHYWE8inZVyIkqnZyrX31Yh/Y4Z3rzAadsJeEmq6jjn3nXGWQDzNO9wZ0qrE3dH@cZm@BJUf57VfZHhr3s@THnZ0QpPRkkfkFBEGZjQQUQ3I6tcQURsAdwV94xhwlINCf@GdSKjsHSNkTp8M2rHCGJyjSaJYr9brFx8PYnUwgSqfoXxDgMQ@JTKuhRZ5fjKFmrV4QiS2/IJcjnddEbN6Rc6xMOpJmb1jKYAsCDPUBrYOqP5nStE9BSFRrChC4SMbudtu2/JYyniRU4LllPLl2hpNignzDoDd4YxlI6JL@LGauhJIeoAUhnaaFDmGNnJkNKnoxQW9QHw9amOEVBXzWSroxrS4@WXuyrNTqu8UTPNN6oOk7bvoORhSlhKAdn2eCXDhjoRfjtaWIpsqp08YjtdiGoTVPpcCaZugPYuDxsFR7GJYgu0MRkEC1oDvSq0wfNot0YeCRO4dj9ti0yHnAjI0g@NFSJYCzqmcZlJ2w3Qw3BgvEmTt2CuihzDfLYQREUSVtGYxJAFr6rGKHJRjqQ23iMJqKUNgRS25LY9gPSeDAWEoBJBg4Hm9qgQ@2wbuHD1rC0RL6JNDwkjCRpXoFUraooBqOAiXV4sZRM2M7Vasj/GQ9PZkLiO5MwxeJXH77xc7u3stX32LM@BPZ23gwWCmDWsDk2gYYJFGnQMnG98ViIpngV5jQa7lJhB4HFg/g0K3rziSs@PFpMZ@TwHIJgnVHiam4ujRXEsgA4tTJ4I4AOkpqmkilviu0sGOXF13zV/gvYanazHBoaraHg19sJr02Du84IILSHI2ckTvF43FcmG3K7IJ59WEL4S96Wcft1R28ngp9XZntoaFT18WghKl707/WuSPD1n7RhAkDBJ9NFwXSoF47HClKOrWGFcqi0uBQ1aIvigpea7kH6JSLWwLKfAwcphlMBvTyt6WnKc6OJGxCmOcBI1bxCFFzHdXZmbhz7IrKWTmKmMyENvB8uBndsxWEO9gPAXyldoKZj7TuNoG6MCX6stdqTbLYoE@6r1zgclgOuAKZHmOlO5jWS6OKWqtJbpilHiJLnnhx4Ce0C6rCOCJeMTDzucdJqeJaVS@QIGohlNYkfxGz/PMcnWQBTvog4zxFXk4UNB/RtwPPo3zesrGEKT1KqRAMpMenEnEA0W6TS3BHcgUcUXqsUBorHm2@R5VcJvHuUR5gX1N1YksOetJUQFHjnFnEpwX2v3p2bIlyBf45@VC2UFA@Kv0D@@0nzFqNb17imy@I6okaAiKoNMORzy36TP2MIUrALDmL05cECOLiS4YNrEeSN1KwUj2RtOdJ3QrN7cuAK5BdbSmEK@uonCSYNYVsIE@k8k6mM5lrUSr0BTZeLa80W7KwmhZs4np4Yms0eRK06kNiUq4BYjsKIq1ABNz@JGB49kAnyduWuoti7OpJPE@HWJYVKhDbT7JA9jDPrqTMQ2yxLdliu4Dj@BBfEN8@yBt8eVmYOR7hjadfxhvp9Zkj/W/BHJU/hzteSO54UcC1h7lj3Jk6tCJRRCcltXNjOOZqQXtwuzvoD9A@1NN@YidylgaAFjy6k8ymeJB8Dvu2YjkRqfgPW9H9CJ2Etnf3jC/s/I7s/E4B11x6LDv/Uzuf/o07vys7v1vAvSZm5KVoJ8Nff7seByJhKvwidnhR3OVi5pf2dE/2dK@Au2nMMP/hPU3/Tj19KXv6soAZE/jAgVO4PszNLImUGsfVauBukVEZiFOYFTCeK03UvfC6aUv0hjfedRGldfHF@L@S@L/C1Yie6khWW4tR9nV5Vk85WJ4lS745D4OsuCfcXxnqpfdXbliBPiI3KF6kybA1lYoKCOQWfwxOmzKB/Bisvv7msy7OvLZTbiXODKsp0KwR5s1girPkS4VVAtYnzMgztKQdN@unW/@LyTCyf5JRaIA8Du0d3jMkdxJdBcOx4teyM1p3EHZD6hwhVpHkJGRnMtrbZ5cnq1c1SmwR2RfjlQQ@auN0yZiBytE8gMhkBLTJyPpKq0LXXKVe8BvoOxeK77Ls8Rdx6beSS78tiLpUDFaRypYGP8mLgZ62vbv70B7AtTL4BydgzoLyD8yq/xccLiy7f5R6SJ32W8fzNrRkUYaep5vLCCwjwmVKN1BmWsArY8ZX6H/w3k8@tW1o2ZZBWfEM4/htuYG2C/uq03V6/evBjz@Nxu7k56k3u7m9my9@yScMQyXnT5mctVB530gzxXK@5sQ0EUnanNayNgcg0DCfZKtJ2BCSzOeTZqtQ2L40Bc7PEedj4vOBAACJqGNviPckkZuFnz2chpI9GKKxvR4d/XszjDkHkqWG9uiqa4t5QaD/dTpvCfQGk287QEggEdlhUh1YPSemadK9MPLKiaQOuZC09J96V6f9UZXtcyKRkCjBzyodCKCxxS/qW2haZHK5FJvAfPxl0A1bStgm49eUqfVQLZB8ur1zaRaATB/oCzL8tT2c8Ylg6hfT94RxZn4kAW6dx7zI4S6SM0OBCxrSB7QB@h0zJXMEp1zcX21dDX3X2vFhtALwl6HCIVppP7Zg6vuhOwAMpoJ75LrDUxxf1YIlqWGJV0FngkyIGNb8xh72/FFQ2YoH7FQZ4p1wHymHLFI7NDARQkhi9PyVLgimvsZmXWkp9uvjYQNgfEXuCkugdHyx0lKBJS6hNTSU04c2jWg9Hl5vxunEYzoRMGfLR4JyRAf8pr3fEN/X6jD6t/Z0gIYttrbloY2Mk4H52SeH/5mcTLGJiuTk2t6FeeVDphlmLiEX36dVKKeWX4LeK19iA7TuYAfw9lzVBdzN@pTd8HGk10D5gekc4lAGi@x9AtuRz96KqfN7UqhLJhFpKT/GTbswdyNrT9HHOPUqMtiKDji99pBc6sUlyyvB51c4zphzDPaAqc3uZBvifDaARXwR@DSTcEMOY7qURUmIGBjn5o9O4M61Ja7kD5lfR2KqLR5IG8rTf20GicZXdE4Ba7E7xpZ4iWfuxBA@RBDgcAbkzbgVERvzf2bFtrm6u1AK@@ktC5aRLocGNb677o2OQO7Rfgbl1RPsIfo6vkSIwWWYBZYhqKVWug7j3iA/LXM2Hkm125j7p92mVCvtNsoP7XaSW2FhQhOCtHsvSlfdm2l6al@PbHv892zH89J48/ZkZhgdIOvBgUhWzspJDLXyP2UmCxiH9GZayDz9gkQOfGMkEuEo0@NGQzSO69V3TUHfDBqTjjscOlI8kDJSbdrFO0LLg85MiU0s5alfIxvTChl0KaU49rwG4cI9xMFtt9H9v91Oec6wp43ORvAE/71pvj0VTUo42Kw0KB9iI6YowshgACSpp4j4wdNy7bj58V0FqDgaHhoH6g8UOqR6B7PBbOgcHmT5L7/zZgsUBRYTB7RA@S5LL6FulisfXLndBfzpDm4FfSom1NF/YeqAuDW4dfahsk5bQrDnurMAwSzUR6ASWpYRVBX0yiDI1co1URB2F49sQBBUygNOKg8DQwa9hUi@SGYGHun1KTPcsrz5REqjSf6ZwRaTlkjebSVjtv7wQDTelICWr09rR6VTzPj1rlLHNJarxuKq3wamQQmWrmVIhr9yeJo7DgkV9GUmJdbox3Cp70k0Dr/7GH63ohv1yusq5nNcjTmTtCg@5Qr5@/CnW/Spiv1Cl1DQt/tlDFagcnJaev0gFqjULe179BUtzLFfVzRVO3tdwxSUmDpzVYvuuA@aRr@NLceQV33Gptt4UYe3Fr1Vy0e18gM07w@5M9FGsTGcHms1dVw7P1u9OEgX4XwYyobhI3refHfeNMI1/cUKJgytU5aYa0uVNrWkT8rcXAX/qNSoiMopZTzVPpGvy9AZKeiWWFi8qIAKSmun44HoYqlEhSjGFKJxzXS1auxyZF@B/nwzc/YxDrTw6X4y35@5E/mAUw1z/BY41jX16b7r9M39C@PTfYLbLiaAoROHn@55sboYJ/kqmllKIqpP5iW8faRNI0KMcqVefV8pK3o0tM@hkkC06rH66tOrM5h2MG5Ooxjln7Fk9pmYEUotbcL0hSjPEJIEginDYPgZ/a76U/SqTdMkh7f7Vy5ufrALdwc3XmE393zfp4tEZKk5Bmnpi2Mk6XqMnKA6jN5lf2J3f7POUV8Qdv3BDoFYC1rp1RATV8B/w9@9gxeGHNErdzZzR2lKa62Gl2uFvuNkCn32AcDkWl0bP8ZUjfbkS8i9RLK1eEtNM0rtfFI95k2@AVJ/qV6vfWhEVsMlvrSnU/fufPL7sKbIqXGDJ0lBWsUE0k3AujboiguDVjG6wG7mz0uupRWLKcRDKUtdGFxOZ3bUJQgTM7tNFxEGv75qMhPRyu7d@F@SbLh7/K40C9OpjpX@OEIFvXuATiHOWUkojeZ/OHedQtv/kkTTWfB3otrqNY9Stj@45gUCTLPyfTMqtCD56V5qnfL44ssIvrz96l0LBEJqYQV7SHx9tOPVtwdW@N5gOFwl@Poq3nxZXpYS5Yqamvo3XyUv1yuN2un7iihXX1eb4n3p9LwSEZuneDZ06/BBtmxq6vTxQgigH51QaQ0nNQWig6EVFAfH51gU7Ian4Wgz6vkGTUv0HA4HGcySHpc1dIuqn@9n7I6d2JZUE4FeXohL8RQFDdWSvybRekVfwnXu8HbQooQrD4R@TZpR0zsUk249STTMcLAEedvidat4j@WyQXgobWg8SiH6BpRFwPlLc3kRul639nZcbUmKyFEhSDTXZsQ8H@6cB4rdcue2lzsHBPuq7kkE0a6VgUZTAO9hzDqu94cjBm0@jhhohX801TCqJUQ5M6LLL59QkAvCKi6RDbdoFoRPw2TQ2z@cBUVSrYRxpibt0ooCy9qj68k6U1Q/Rw0OUudPUYm3liaw@dgUPnaHy0OWX9m/5LR/BTq9Rf9v@rtI7Fm89dAlF/HH99aKU/2HAJkPDHfsUhjZFKpn5cq7yhleSSP@Ufn4oVYvo0m4Ed0a5MXvkSH0PbHJhOrpNmfdwKoqcDHKRjFz1T1RIMdci6HbgVmBI0HGMtqJ58FRI4Pn4Bd4kDcvh06K1UE8LRNkzkiGqbEEg9lELK/zdMzMHUJwO8v8QJk0H5q8XB2vp1iqu1izbj6mLuanX7ft7RX1123/RVx9ssyysUjaqxAj/rNYIUT766U@RGiAWTVAD0/ypeEzf98BFP9@I0jWr68cP2V0@qMG8dVfg@j/39V0zco7cZWHa1bejak8W7flvbjK67b8ciXj@qbOZe61RNRi9xnsLO1uf61If9KKpOyeDy1K8YOGdr@/hu3PHDayvH7@wJEh8q@R@zNHjm3Bnz90aA39a@T@zJEje/TXSXBoiIwMIhlIo/ih6h7FLtwOu1egXZMAhD8@JEKiRTOCQmDNdFJrkMlctzFUJ79MIfxSXe9LGY2ddtDqLc3WQnmsS8YqXK7qddh7433pVLytlasncR4cSwTynD9sSm@Tou@TLbDk4kfyvokzmk3bbFpem6oiFgg6CfpjjuH9sZMM/ZJaqvgl2YZl@zGu1uwv69cz1/B9lp67d1MX4889vGFJhXiP7JnGgb4dpVTGS5VPa@d1GNh64zMmetf9fQbWnaykI5s4v4T7b9lBX62BUU7yF1ee1NGeyVKIGXzeSsY7aGumToql6Q1dO0CN3mKSe369ZPoNt5H@mjbS67Wx@TVtbK7XRvZr2shm4xpZsSyVK0fnr0VWNN7UPsSXoS/eNV4Qhbc7daaOM161hIXXMKjz@/B6rOX8T7MCRnYIfzT82RGp9Kj9Xi5HP4F04t9joS9C2uDw8PHoDMYqhfJaw0MXoP2B4/M5@0XcGDFV@JjiN6XnClv8We0sTQb4kCGe77D3PVt1k7znYZJAaZX33JtpRz9PodS0OEb8JchMm1qKnHpwB8PblMIOtBzig3FeKt8Dhb4KlUmU7waJ51t2TN2CAY9tJPDD/ZpGfC/XpXZCC5MST4g7L8bxm0l832MXy8DbubXkAHzZSiJGyUvFkESIWDAbOqB0Oo1VPiWZUZOFT/cgExIoeLxfjUeMB3AsrrFez0slV/syL/N90Ly5kqBL4xwLLxJy4gNfdp02V8SP@RNB5mgOsYc8R6LLI/SLJAoPHrnNQ6mcw7VF0tIjeVaSk4/TAlnTEnNYgvDfuAV/bZfx2Imw3gDHO4Zr15TRZcLGynlEy/1QHa5uxMylWBjhanESG578AsHjqb1ic9T4eikYkThCagF8xr50nPgQ51PVOLZ@5NQ/sj70lGIRTGw8PfendjJ5v2Jt4DlG9f3LE5AqFhDdjItT1HE7XIUaIUHajifpAnrm6pJYSItXSpkrp@@Ess4F0FfPLbkTT5AqZ@7Y@QIS8t9HiRjDgeEJ7Pub2Es2Ek0p46NtEivSJFZQAJF/xk3ZCQnVr@XpMLuuQod1xJKoV0pl0WjWxcn52bGonjWa@KJ2Qh9Oq2eVmFOdRfyw6NufInhLUfsySP249sobBsQb4r/SKkzavCK4HHvp6UbM7o/9I1z@yBwj2oeiteIoi@JlPGHVCBUep0F8xRbAvgwU8cHlg4AGnBPj34AL4qnxMF88qg1oGsHYFd4NJvXCzcSZgw7iJc1116hWYYeXJdyrf6OdUhMQYnfK1WJHzGIUJy2vsOepKzE@Y@CYhHQffIxsIdVMdUuGsXLeUYH8Crtf4OYkF4Soh1NoeCL6W@kIVt3ScbNSFm8rzTe1csP/FHHmxTjdaJTucuibFoJrRoLzk1dO/2YcjTGl0Ldxd03IHDsbG9aaoVxN8SGvmc7QBRotYUS3vydXRusdl05PS0enFUmaaMDe3OlIPRZz/rYn9uw62gNWY1XErV8MdvtpMpL95VUyip4OIdItGozIu5BuLetFiiChTeOxyHOOFwek/Xht2VSQGEcrl2E6BKltTAMzixoGcoFId0Q6rwekP9Wijuk6HZk2nV9bmB5p7NzRVLP9pLTG/4RA7jXDK3MyujIXF1yZo9hKduqnkOj9IMYycbiT25Xx4I/FhTOJZaqjcJC/mLjDRX/owjM8AMWzXec2O74ZDg3c8ruDXi88CPrz4TfbeCOm07l2BWDz/wE)

Nim 0.20.2 is separated using `uint64.low` as described in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215669):

```
echo if compiles uint64.low:21 else:424
```

Answer (score 1):

## 430. Python 3.6.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 1):

## 435. Python 2.3.0, 18712 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rcyPZdSD4saPT8yMuE6wCQCDfeIMAyWKxutiql0hWd7sBFCqRSADZTGSiMhMkUCQrujUOrWTJHluWbFmW3bI8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsanm84dgEMvM@z7333HPPPee@sqP7g5/9LIEXeeLa077tBiQw/YB0PevE9ERyZ0q2dcvPqxrHYagdrz8emk7gV7gEUQixdac/1vsm6Vl2YHpZ4psm6Zi2ewr@KiGbY2fsm9062DRCHPOU7DuG1QUIJHCPTcd6aXrglyPkrmmfD88DYrjDoe50fTLyLCegvnlCnuhg6Y2NY6J3/MDTjcByHfAqLCRRXLCVCHnoer4JkFzD9H0XYZUXgigyeUeH9Ea2ObkCWVHI@5bpdQnNxcgzWV4Ulbx3dO/eVVeNfEFwHXIPc3jFK0d2xoG7H1yFnyc7fdPRiSqWRfWqZwHwFJh2SS7JV72KUFVmYBlX0ymRnV7PckzyEMp61bNMDN8XfMOzRgEHVUnuWR5Usx5WJzF0B6oNK3WDmMNRMCUCIwTdtuNK9onuk7E/1m0azhkPO6YXBfQD3Qssp09OrWBAgoHlx/FoaH@kG6bQNW1raAVml9gWRHJ7IRQA7XTJsTk9dT2o@xCm69hTiGgaVs/CKFE@ACBeqWBgMjhDfQqE4wRAJUQnPmTDNiNoaS4B4e@anXGfuONgNA4I5K1r@XrHBqCdKemaPX1sB1nSAT@oEup@OjCdkKoBnAggjlyWq4/GNGvmjPj1bpfIQNCQj2OTWIA1mq0K0TRwJ64HWINQUY5CYJTAWRnNCdQw1FnPrZC8LIP/XuyCudVt3w0zs5g19HSg0dI6Q7hPPLfv6UPARtekOH1v/wnxDdcDG9wYljWsm8AYekA2N0ly79HdJKnH1SJ6HS6uoho5gypIRJ7kRLfHQCHzNeFC/XhxbA6rLLmWrJAkoEWVSS5HctB@S0TNA5IUuQwGYASqpsBdIGqJ5BRob3miQWBNhcZdAB9oECQn55NZTLzn6X3LNhnoPoIuYtuBOCo85RzRoFloBY2F7rt2jwU1aC6KRCuRQpEU86QIzzIpq5ANTDMHLSYPdwFugFiGPAIgVYMcyyoDNmsUQMRIiLukpw8texqmQJMwSF4hRYAKhVEAuloCKPDWNLw1uEsIbfGahx0MoCoG@gmAF2zrGHmZGbMzrF8JXtLGhkT5JjJmlrw/wOQBr4DRfIkUIfkCYCQHWQC0qyVIPi@zgvgD07bDaAMfo9HcFmW4IedFwEUJqkYGnMqI1CLcYAfWqQKPVIEhqsDjVOBLqgpmDZOAcFhXBajnQo4lM9D9Y0iIpaN2aQUA3wcwCmIc@aGCSAIIUGsEUA00kAMq0ZBK8hqB/ENeigUCFFBSSClHSkUC@CzLBOpHgXwhCSnAihXIj4LAgA4UIAQF8qQAthUAqmh5ws0hW9HQH@JqEBdQo@QgTg7MUHFKAW@IB9ShQJIKpKmq5RmFQt7UPJQ3r1HSVQtQu0XwA7ypkFcVSArpVS2BP8YtAQ5LSNnFZJYhQkc8QK1gWwBaBGTkIT8ULoQFs1oMiVe3RwO9g4yfxez0MGoB20gB0QhRZSwevHOITciKDGCwNUD2VaAAjTYleOfi5G0FgDQQvNm1KPe2sQdRYgwVs5QgP9JHwQxtSoHmaDQNBrGbytxc4KoWcEazrxvT2BNaYTb2nLkWNHRVKSOeAZJz6OoD23XHvj0DEhtyKk3KPLHsmVuJunVNvduz/MGrWV5zNJGOqQeOdTxLJZ/PziFVn/MooMeCU1GbDxtYAvRl/QGaZmVRixhm5MYVtJBlRaHZ65i9sdM3hXJpLn/UJxh7AfQ6szTLzNmz@n3owWdwlCwtJu1FZ855mkNb06BzjxwRu5imZ0HffpsYA5BNYs8yg18uz2BoKsKY6h3s8gWQ1aCLKGOn1rMmpHPboF3KLIMaxZMxsEZR4MrKwHOVSxOZlApztEEx97Ikx@wZr5b4kWs5qSRJprkLDjoiJn/Od@PQ272PXRh2yki60Om6VKSYsc@UE3WbaUDaogQAXbKNklLHNHTsnrGzMmlnG8GxApFAIiBEmu4JCre0x1xIxqe9asdDWRZEoK7peQTDggDsZ2n/6487vvlijELWLF896NBN6Pd7umXHGaD9iB5Q6QDeSR/Smy5mu@e5Q9rZDLF/tV13tEKWgd78FAHdd0/NWdZnnb0@GtkgUoG7ySQ6yMypTqVyKsLPp8oyBJEwHlQ4AKRJgShieaZBcR8WHWJrILQsZrFC1PptDaHcmZO1NGgsIIf4GMcZ23YFhCDTIFpd6ponEroweWxRDsM8RBIayFkhiI4OYjfmnOYihnRbFansdxTVrO8OF4vG@tf9uOgDC6Um@1SfQu31oGs1J/oQlAOCEji0XDIEimE1iDUBWgQWa590XScZxFBOPZBwodBxSagUjTgJrKEJOpILUbDGczTT2LvTnHWmQMoUWzmRKkUsJ1cQJXJXEcUccnMOrLGALNgdG4g1TNtyKAWBuOSjAuABq2RuXOCRZlOH2wNhbxTqgSIaMOAhZm1OnfBZaw/FcoNCRAHWdHzQUHyRWKilAeX33R4Q26kFZQeGBVFnsA2KBERB7DQRDZGjKEcCGh7bxCLGaETAHTolIM97cgnkU/cji7wET3sA@oUx9rwpmYygJqwhhAoMt9cD6n1pjgYAggy7xJga0Dyhkin1@ANHH3Fdl7IZY7RY2Jlt3YQwDuotu09@kfRNQD7ItD3UGpHwZ8UYjWhBKEJ0h8m7jg74woIYoylFDpeYxei5rojuXdf0Kcm43nHMADAx3@zTBgKtrTdjSUOU34FWHap3dIH/hI0M4WOC3NLCYFIhLbxjOtCADKBNaPpQiVizO6QHCvmcIIuqiG4Y5igIqcWlTM1y5lSCx/dQJaCuQghM9Afc@jbZvEI7EDSmnzmJFlUkzPoo1FR05Lih1i9Q8SPWShl/safXkocQJ1dS559jmIUcPOdX5GFEGwbqR5RVjANkKMgjLWOAHDFAnkOlbmhz3vh68cFtPnlvSIRenDbmRgHmw4lS7IT5WA1DgNu@Dkgc2QirvuCAQRccXgNa94dLILtxJu3uvKso6SKwxtcBHbqOuwQqIDOGi0EWfWhdUGI8RN6h2zEx0ubiL9QRsu3ZQBR2Z9CTjkauBy2DsZ4pHWygVTZHXaGOnop7jLRI7ix2sNBxJLHbD7AvhAgjWwdawCaGLRX0Kx34BbAypkMD53NZinMZpq2ewgrzd0o7AEZM0KM6jokqmu5NGRAoHnTSkNCUWJ4HzPAEuwrWE0VdikjpFHoGvdtF/orooO3@auIiUvTuuGNNrirqBjqKH/ncie6RHuroHoge0IhSyZ6fTFepO40558VL7iiQaFT25CEgDSRClad6oPZDV3EPGM3h1DFS/EIT47OEHwe9Ep8GA0Zkkhp5FxSGq7lDJQKJZngM7ZraqqQPnbggwFNAN5oT9JBE9NA9kDagEYKuWS53Ozo5B@7hEWGyyxSSSDFRxFyclul047RCRGBe5ssrsiR8z6AGYa5vwxJgcFpy2kksIPANMUEj8uAgSWEPiw5U5mN@VLphjmOHDuyRFBNI0uQsFoGhA0jRzFgggliGFbRDoeX27Uh8WavVgNhApgK22U3P67XRoKcInBoCi1QmCRMRA/cwwLaRSkN5MfAFyw0IT0CptTo5CwYetDhqv@AgEKCVc5CSI8SG9fzIOh53r1a0g44YiMdWB6KTZQR8lQMRgLWG2k1YTS5gFXTfJGIViRfjU9DXiJe6YoXyYTDP9FEIroVZmavhFOYgpNWlKGJRQ7cZQe9ODTsUCZgJGjvjRh3I/nE41hUzomwoE0SN9lpLZUCwOTA45MnO0f1a2BaZp9SxnMqCg@0auk2d1zE4H8V9sH/nYOfgF9tLYNhWp3LVQbJypQJ2teOJ0HfGUk5UK@vzMGaA77Zvho0RF8PwXOhNBHcyJypNDehcJhE6Hx984SpKQBJCdNAUwIz3FZGGhQGhi@vo/uBKJ0z6mQwkGUeJwhJhn0QwYwNmHf31KD9Pxi9fYuVdzdQodMec2WOdAYgcpX0niiei5xUBLPLq9FiPSOOCLGo5OJExM82HjPLzDsrOVzNDBeo5knnn8b29gxoFG46uCTSI5AcgS@leVwSat8egiC8LA@wPTAbJiLOMo1RN87oUwYaxgOBZ3ZIV8AEAajyiSwR7GBXNH0Ded6@WjboKRkwB1E4hXJUr5@Uh4/NmdC4f2MUZqPgu60Wpx6yzip2W9lix72K3ZeTzZjFXnu@2jFma3XmgdN4A@oFIbvTA69gX0EWcSZGhWB1m//DBtYz7VIgEVUCIcubbRKRp@TaH2otgkaQv7YKe5tqm@D7leDzh05KUjKYORMOnKuhc@L2JFaTkNHsraQgLqe/s7Kt3o8DhwDUdz6BKA2rk2DN5PZwLNHygEce13b5LNiAOkw6jBEFsWlnMnb7rXKshHR2xqAmcTgT@i8M3@gj6GuslVR9prHmllU1M6o5/ClxaKWiIJIohCkqi4cWP9BMd0DUr9@H@h3vQiSh5WY7NMr0ABXNxKLrQZMy5UgciQEJimJ@lBYznH6@19shDmJsAxEKHjC6OuDPzXupIOaYoLQ2/NEvvutcw/pE7vUJa4MJICwxzKNt/9OTB/qO9hzsfNAM1n1@w5@RyARAH6XVAFhIHDG/YWjdY08RiIbgEtA0PmxdwgTEoKNGE0tj3gHGLGERkGVhBNWzmNvWuO3CSfvpqYU7RV/jIMRgJPcTGx4KGEUHR7tqojHhsZhv7c6SfQRCM/IokQSsfjDsiKK3SR4Zr632JxoOOwbYlBVWX/cc4uuEviwGZ8acmi8GGuEB0mNJxRN0euqC80PlxZA0kxcDTsSvb6g9AF8ZJdNNLizEF09JIXdAQQFeW4rJRBkxtgNvwHdUTz0j7bUUtMbpWZDUn8VGwheYPYdd6JqhOKeitABXpK1bSvN28TabApRHSVSAJIm7QQQ6fYF9gExAk6dgp6vkRcii3wFFT5BUURy/GOKYLXErKy7miUshLoJaBmgYyq4Ajb8JQD4yBELgCwBPcHh03mKPCnm/oTk/cCA1RZkHuuwVF1RrPmk2nBQJ68zbNG05NN6athtJKV8n1KBth@HQVqHeheEi7kQPQLjUCadI3WcHPuvp1dtbVaevqEikYjsI@RxiRhzsgSL10gV93zfm2hxGkeU9pYyGshIFfSUsGhGyMyuEDMSVBg4KeFkhPwnwJIPSieAiUA3xrLgKZjWbEAtM0GAD/0Ehql5rS1yVcdNZCrrGYFRwaFkdTYHk0EDJtQcMMRR40wRGDgFlJggqEEg/6J1kW6EDCkQcsfQTVxAa0dqEjAHXOx6HIALtgnLMZs7FhbJKhFQc8d4QPiS68vEm4iEID4MsfftYL4cRim0ju6EhxgIUrkl0YUSRPkQVAXz4lAR1p6JqoxuP6iKeOhYqIyFFfAbqu5HpbDLw1wkNalz/808tPvnv59U8uP/nW5Se/fvnpH19@@u/XhFeoY9Y3M82mIGYbLcInr2X@1p56a@fOrTslmkOQJyHz//cv/frf/cavLOZ9Sbo//vhrP/74l//2Vz75m88@/vHHX/rJj77@kx995Sc/@uobpev8X7/qGv/tEzdM8hSHRuYTDNOD5AYD6EXvg9TW2Lh1ekbW1tYg@traFtTE2tYWyZAteArwXIN@cwt8s/DcIg3wXSMtctHiQIP1yZLRPpGOn4umbgzawC0NM6WlRejyzs4n52QwaExEaOfHvLHBty7o7BLtC3DGhWV6FyvtkC6Rwby/C903s80yvyrphtRsyM1W8yzV7GbSzQspq7RAy25b@PBTarqhiKIAbshbUpJ4VrqQ4rxNaEgIJBoDb5YzOmHHVuygLs0I/p41gZ4IWCUQ0vyYPGUtdHIHh1Y/NEeDqTcfIB6vAvkUx55nC0FwvQzyv3n@8pLFnxeFFnTkSGJk4UAsxGEvlDRGU8YXOZbTprSwDinqsU6E3tANdOk9EdQNca6jSa4lJUGAPoT6MEi02A8t3wDVQndMd@zPj9EtHTrE1MH1aDAG9r07sEacaQxcoPRtgEniWRJEMk74CGzaKIrWNUS4sVkjy8ApBuiN6RodCyqftl46iqHQpE902@rGY9n5wuiFGKdWpXGIjAlZfcf1TAEQATE4uiCJrnfj6tFs7j4dKbrGK0Nf2gUg37XMIEvu2a5OMeo6QAtz1IhzIbP4oM9ClAOzy9kOEXogWoisBjyzK21wdG7T9QbALqE0OGWjxnU0DD0k1x91xWACUbkUdlDznkwbAiHtlHRVVS0Y@V4l8kNaAGQPoGpQi3NAJYy8BAU802HV7rFhlEinffT47h4ba6CdE3ZHOO7UHrrdMchhoZ5xYDr9LNkDKrIcdwis1Inivzy2D1w3YFoxWFaNZDAl0xqObZ2OkVwdxrgxnuF2XJsOndwUdRZ@7Pm6rbNBm8h3572HIBs/PTqsiZW5QJJ@MrwxbRy3W54sw@f@/EwdnaWMplN8Rpj8ep7Hbi5aUYnMJfQooccQ10yCrBhq0dQaO4YBzxT5AsOuVDficAoNx2SkWUJnikrdT4Jeb8FZo87HAvISe@aco85sHeWCOuR1ZoHyLBAuqlwIMw@oQMPEaytXhivScGw5BxDrzKNEPXS60lLAofsF3zL1nS21ROkn5GDxhP3AtKMJuANz6OIkE/SSNs5mgGiPgixbDGlCXzHCuQTKpnGGCroEHSJeFbSgiY0EFppLrNFm07EcCSeKuHWJhCPEVdpwQOtmM3s@Y6EuaMZ08GGzzmaEUfPwmNIjsbHr9TaA2KxXo8Vpq4JhSslkHIxCpXmDGLSYdBL8WlHjJQ0@HZLmaJQq50sgdE9UWWhOinut86TkUzT0CN9sTm7J6gcgk@Cyw/XbUt@s0vVAK/BVjXySlGGHfTlHQ7HhXWMA3IVkJouohPoZOz3X7gpsLglojTAtBCsonNCPl0OGq15Ny4tWQtKlqCwqctW5RZTX4F6p0vr1AHPLLmNAKD6Q8@PsyTlpHGfJieiPbCsAEQnliUG4qsi5ukCTzmfpnqdPfS5cD1IjOwfvvNeQWwwCN9RxfqjEanESrfMFrc1zx7gyG0y4qiWwAtrr01l7C8sLQg5EoFMJkH2AwRKokjihsERU8jHPZ2XpmaDPpUwqLk2HWWKmL8SerQeB6TCaY5N0q9HNZlPCZGo0@a1waL5CZDp/YfUgl@AHWaySw6O7ewcHIgp0qeQeznNUoDmC6AjCyKpCR5icL3yF3OomyS2Mk0blloOmBup6O4wPRF0Foh@bOJuDbKdveilwTOMUhQHOdFaIRmTSWIggXJtkBBRHMbAUKNtbDFhlaf6fOseOexrXeAUoPkMxCehO3a6glJkWx471QvShe6GCJgQJ9SnoJWrrKcrJ1pV0uPhsiBOsIFRTARFK0GgQ0Jn4dQjMk1arymbKISz4gRtil@dpVdDl4DUlqvoaOIMgQyGE0WuvyLOGLJRbmfVloOhCrHAlNyv/HFyEsAjaN5cmu56i7f1aQ2Z5YDNmjHs/9enyx8X9DBWyzgw8G5mlwaPFRZTp0LVIi2uKFlcsQSNDVkIHLLAgEUtIhOvsQ5ql/pTzg9aL0ahDKk3OYqSriHJyfk5xSNZVQnEIJoWwyriItGJgTA9cKM2DcI39vExAW2u43ALbbJPjK7E2L8qizKMTk9OlkyvCqHBCfSPNnAmDlnPs0umQ2NSWRSWPAmAce3hsX4@JKzXpYyEonUydhVWX@DDhbdjp0ceSAHRWIJxvpg50vDkUfUFm1KUD@qJDz0tSXlxjsZBsuIaTdrFgJsKL14QUyiUauNfpWKuCAhJw8VT0XhIMuBMSsirmRGVWxKvLcMgCfsNFpeH7v3/cBTxfr4UB9AQ4ABcb2tA3Y40IvZWVEkZFC30sr0A2Tjy2LZ0igJpeB9LQPSiSbseG5aDpXLQgQP8@xJH1sGaBBvEBEuUN5MRyzibGovfyRJbNLTnAE41VYa8sS2JJ0VkQ0Ne6FAlMyrFMGonyJlYJ5oTNRMzpy8inXp@paO0QoUTL6n0wDsbsCULtayvRGuF9UxsMQ8p5vaOYElvGfUOVe/rxuOsKo@N@LIgWloSdlZ4OEwnQ34ezom00Li8@KyBbFh29VwWb9V3SKX29jip8Z@yPhA5VrrvMRhvC8IYUPJs9VwWxwv1usWE11iybPt6QEkPoQCjhogAJF14Kc0izrqDZ1jtTFDIGn5/K4gl24Dg1I5ORtRUzrKPR6vioUNL45fLy2BPRYPhYpvpLbHFnqFnRAofLPV9Tq9AtWUPdFtTunHEl0142P38taDy1R@PgTgS6HeFGIseOxxjbujcz3UDi10aTr41Lh93CE8twoZ8fEaUoKuqMOUZrwWYgcRUtfczN91vLEBbtohBi0/LG7hoBrpFcQT1vwLrY2kRcATpHDqK7CieGe4r3SoFgAFomey7vu14uzdUbsCHBNmwdeuaVjH9hdA9HD19DkqeWb9LHcsQeL81oYNhL3ReJPRq3mx@Hex0B@5bt@uSQPm9CUN8DLLDnctKdx6WlOwIdw54338Btokn9WYXqdt@1C6W@pMNjZa2PvR5y@PD9prws5kWK8hpeFAk6rqOE75Uc/Fjyjl9XQXSfnocLOueMN3SmyxhSOGmxunQg4@OGheUluyeXaExRYmN7KxLGZSyn@jR6/xydxCrURp3EaEoFZJDjMEK5BIbAY0Lzz5Na7ubUum/GlK6BLb6uEHOVe2yb0C3R57UqJaqsfM4Yiiy/OYvq2WNzbC5VHR53PjLDDuPNE5fD7K6HQ@o4io87L@JQL0Od7o1yhz0v2m5kGjrO2r1eOFlkXiOQp0eo7T4BwxM0XI/Rd8ajhdpb0KucA4aawShqom53IRfo83n5Suk1Ms6CZO2b9L5R12G6Ga5wquVlWQ5Fj7kpkAXLTTqQFsf9yGLPhYSpyyzlWVic9vLmjMvToGiZX0O3kqWoq1RvGrhclhzLMYMpPt@QO3Zc1/48NQVMEve9uqBnCnSt6E01dk18CXdBkNnggo9DEp3eqmEF1nuEWiHgB9Xdmyp9fo7mjWpTwFnIIc4QLVqXp4EjhrY@7HR1kuqcuunrQHFLJg7SsMWi9mpRMByeUMSSWJzVTtftmLbOXpNC7qZ4ZVFb0rbDyU@cLGVTpLMJ7cQV3jGaQlmtLqgHA3NoUusN4rXexVMcwtfKQBMX71XeE9M0pMmeaawKMLKgWTv4XJiTnZNdAtcBxSbAdWaoINi4kjF0XY2sh7pnuQ92Hr0zP7keBtgf6n3zXqQdzA0J4EIZpjjNjMsHByrkDjYlA6KFYEPB0jk2p370Xhrx4dSAihoPVzY6A0cH36CVrVr7eL0LcwbuwBmYA7bgOLatolIgpIACDqnH6Q9wrdNotLAGeh4Ptmvb83hAFsMYjuv2lqaxh3shcQvP0vhsg3X4eu0wlR6wxoeGlWQ6MMfAx303cEemQG2rgto4pMGeq3hONFX7846V3KjRAiqi988L/7W6VV93g9GIvtoje@zTB40q0K2qr5MnemxtBV0F53p98aU77IihoxguvKCzucvbdMcKjAHuFWYUafbdjjGwXpfp8HwCKRrcYNY30t0QMxYR7qIzKPSAXm8qIr3U5v0P8bW/qtLDcRLWGcSGG/r3ZWNRdDeuMNKPDZ@N@6GJVHDoc651sT27FbrrufJibAUzoHOLceKBTDbQjoZVeQ/XEKyUROii@Bk7DNcWrKRSKryioCqYMggIyqpkF5dnzTUxTWOPpbzBcI3jXsSeV2IyXJdCh7isucFHcF8gnYUFNUsla2cw7vvXeRsbc@6CtIKP1Ro5XZc6N@4K3YLuhK9VGFRtCTeswbsN4sfYvHFiIH/jzAANp9iC7lrwasMLamW8cnjItkY@exKht3LeKFxnA2rm1ckthpvpcj0xrJiu2WPj@Gh6nUwG@jUIr33ozwUD53txGBj5NOu0GU9y3D7wa8Ems8BR2FW60tJ1MMurP@7ehA8emX0dF8U@sAJcPriEKmj7WLZ@5rWwvzjWfeuLYyjZKmLDPfhszsybXz2JtiXwHup9y7i/UBFxJkMEh2sP2WuB/NHpel2cDiwf193EhhvGXJDkGBEj1bVBhF4S8urgc3z8wKwBsS1tS0MvGyB2R1Pc@TOlppvGhq2ADiCG71Va1KpVTjdm4nQ8HI398LU8D3Rlz/wA65CxM//UAuDCC@CaZKDbwfJB2LnRRBCkwv5uZlyeZIV8aNlun3xYkgnIXQGxUM5dQjh3oOd9gstGPGcJJdK033DuDnV@gclt/guoWxMXqDtWcPMARhDgEpLojYVhnYJ7CvLAA3yK258XgnC0HCMP5jq5eDvpa7pooLBDd@wZJhrjMyLmJfIQurkbrYC1cFc9nnFxOq/ZGK4NzQgM9tKmYbjOOBC8sXMj9y/cyP0reE7QXHWT1Bf3Hj5Nz9c6XSf8OkEyOklqZlo5u32FmCwHZKnV/HIxdCT232Un3BzQ5aqvibODx/AYlC3fdZepIE@m0FEsY@bj4V3TwLms16bxyH3oOi70LiNgfMMDk@3HXlhlsDwiRnuAO44BD93XJnNIwa7oVJj0oI/MDtSjPTO9Sd/CAN/VA31F10KHvahKFpteSxOW3TG9j@h41px5lda4mKH75oSqAasJg7U1ITAMJr3iUNNCW1iYXPBHruuwJ@WeMryUhzdzCWDt9PHms7ciLvpeUL2XqlKLRX18wpYumF12YMCqsnpmx7XZ84YFMY7FJqp1zzJ96QHuP6duhRwRQJryb@QVxRt5xUyLAcn0RPfpzPFyrWAGUpl8jnUpA90zXJy0CQ03LBmZ2zT@GnYcryNns9kdQPwEOJNujMPjHF@XLXvYGdLHSgVgrjYPTEimiwvWDqdOoE@uVyYbfAm3mc8tM4o3Z0dsCRt1gaSegHaRXq7AXcGeNaIPynlXzuDSlSKCY5nGSx0HmlyKl9nw6oI/lE16RI0rhlvnmgsdCJV0utt4aYtZXDcFgohtCsHAAzVcCm4aoY2OulgypD8emjjvuTiRsFLkdP0BLay7fIo3ZqKeKYSnrgHPiE9gY3KdsLNSYkTw8H98510JOtV2IRcd/wAs6vWTypD5seeErzehtCeuH/SsyWPIN64xX8U2sFh5iAIv1gLQtLGqEFB7zthmAwL9uUU/wy5VowR6WK4g2JQtB6ZgOicCPYxrcr1ELts@JO3gOaqB2RXCveg4WC48iHYSxcHC95I5vXkeiCsKFYkhdlLIhWsMlyH3NOIAID@5gTDy6Vsa@U/2Hzw@Eke@srQf2hng2vtrctnC5na1JM@NEn2ke3NTc2wtVNfyA@nOoSLsPtgXMcAKfLPRewFeOLm08Fo5FBmdpynpK7UX9DWD5QLf/aOHDzKzjXcktTvw3KGZnvfePTzM4j6Gdw@Xes/Hvgeto@dOVkbf31OU9BLyDXdnruKSS1JaBenIBC0SiPE@OxvjtUKU4Y7M7tF0ZL4HnSRyav8Nky@sLOQj/cTqYysk5ZWIog2VlMVCLj23/BeUZNOL36vq89gaIbc06Etir5UrJFBC0CRPWy4l3DQ5fVVaIXI4Of75IinydWqdP9FV0v1/asYURVmF50O9B/VK8israzHAsilO2z15g9lQM1RGhNhJCICqBOu1i5WLwhBYt4QPHDEPHcHYWbky4yYAsXNhaYM/NZ2p7ggoLYUuIzeWMj405@Zq4sUiJ3jc89Jpq3i9NUkZ1Bih@cib89rdvbMfeRww99D2zqOn5Inug8azBKI5B3EmWXwk4HgNnuK1auBiv@sBp2b9RH@0nO4r5FD3uq4zncw1FZzFxa6OHlwZx0EbDWTa1sRaxrsNNj7zZPlKkCgNtkLenS7IefMHY4QRLr/864oiy/TYE3wrMrNeIWCSQpM@xTOz5r2O9mPSN7BfFsEhvVSremBOcMUAG6Vcppwu5d@FG3h7Mb2aXd7kV7rBL3dDetf80BH3VCg3AMzf4EfyYuz9wLVPB664q3vmDei4KevlG7JenuM34UnMdPYqNK8WWnElePhaSm9HZuDlRgO3Y@UWROTFDZQrh9sD3aPrD/puuHie2ZcndTqOGvJD/aU534SPZ3zAHIxxyfiSibQOCGKm07fYwWvkjhvsUdsN2kK8P3T5XLM1ujseXWEleEb9Fe70Pihl7qlP7uCOn5l8uES5xLVFy91XCVMkHmHCMwbvH@1EiT4@lNS5FGe5@ODJgjPuiQseH865eeZkskrbEiarlJelPrNUHx3lFpLdrD87ec2@CujZgNXF75VdLuM77x5eb52oKQyCoR35vKs7ZgSn6wZ0k1Q8DjcZzQZH3x9QAoj42JIFXdCLWBbA8KV2Gw8tabdXUcmR@QEdWIa@kgTmBMV6JuCHZwOZk9wgCL/PQaOsbADuccy1D0cDy5mEluHMHde6kdRHflTiHXJou6ckUnjmmk/YY0EU/cR0bt7UJJS1mztkbb7XXcATO/w/fK1C0Z0Vvfcd0/OWhTkwpHuR5T01vSTEu4dRgGW@u7aLg6Rdazxc5k2jZjLLvLyFhn01krXMA8@uPx64nrPMM6qYSuWOuRL02g1@wyloa8s8Or3eMuc9313m/HBsBxYKaZHnI3cMrSciqz0vkt7qm/VmU6yIMysexesPvPS8C3CKoTv2Qbyz7PTVoMJHVrDgeAXf1A3PAjYd0XGvwn3XJV@wZvmcL8TLlVh6997MZ3GceIwzhXR33My4aqfUaKq9lnxfWn1qWU54jjW84js7Zmnfcx1mS8/P@0SHLC2Bdl@3rfTqiVD1NTOhyOaYPznRlrUyYPj35jH63nQSS85PbLplN7TtqlCAvmGkw09F@HT1paLNDQqwJSMrlr3NWPYX94a6MT/kuHDWQjRt5M@Y@Jxm4R0@urNz9P6TB6H9C/qwE6UQHY@u3mWrtuI1GleGUegB8tIhPgV/oEPfRUdQBNw9fWUG7f2dB08idjwAkRxQiWe8zQ00xXyXpLqerw/LsQT5MNqndBfaHppnnOj@1HSFcVwo1t8tU/NX7h64ekbUzaHnTna6VhuPzOBw7PXSKzeyqsuVncMHq9jqu1ExD995@O4X7822OT2yhkQWVfhfaRmiIspXndTrTtp1p9x1p/x1p4IoX5H5VkiD4nKtNAZUvg5buZZ39XpG1esZVa9nVI0yyraAQ0c/f8i@nw0Pe2JHJrCN6r4YfQkhlXKAv6YXPz41v@sej6JOreNRrOt0hz2EPT8na@GudvDgo33y4T5@PLHRcsYmbsRnn6QJauuQTK2m5MtkC7/2VCGKTNPEb@GV2cF4UWINsn4W7lGvVJQLslYjfIUn4SkB8TnX7KxmAIynzEKhiHCskPUAfNajHe6EfnyEnBM6dCoYeJgn2ERp/qyPangGAORp/ezJ/pO9w6Odo6eHDbl1EZ4REJXCcSC16CSSW1qXh8KHeAOVlZ3cTs@msCE5@sUJHHL1o3IR/NjSYtFqC0WbFYrfwjjrZ44jSfSYBEm4gPwJPEuN@qLMCE4MdlRiWkHhCRkVdmIBPXgB6oiB5mmaUGkVIi9LeKT7PhQr9L/6bTLqix@2q@Cn7TDh8LBtEFH7rtsNU/RN8vorSvHezv6Dpwd7JMrgjGpOrW4wqJXz7Cz28Bg2Hg9NsOl5IskwShLqqlZL3ksCYpJiklTowRb0HHQ8si0Z0wMeiRHG3iCpdQofMJiMK0X67x9LF0kR91mkIWwyylQSkgWap4SCh9YdAZGQuwf77@0dEMz/3l3qjChCEOQIN93/5Q@67Esi0VlX0Uf9vGGokkFt@a7VreBRF4ZJEjlFDc/L6RI8542dBkHMCf0qB6U8Oh4095m/ND1/iJs/nyM6tGJ2rgbWHOUA8zHZFz/oeRXxp0biLyZxHD1PD@j9lB4HeeWkxDQ9jYx9wpCdYRqDpqQXfbUA50tBhaRihOVbeFoG1kPPHXtXGgnuYKcHg4pkB793iF9V1OlHcSCzYydgB6uFhy0lgELFmFdlyTrNLPuEDj8XMLm5Bo2kY4ImT3zHAqkxqJCPgIJxrrLCTlMRhHryWpQIdIWaBNQT5wIynXaIR9MTYbSHJ@Q1Peny135F6lcJmAMwfzU0T@Q7YPtaaOuB@evM/ExCApWS176cEudlPkN4cmpYApYRrmf97Gf4CVQ@ta4ox23vJJPMy1V4KNU8yZNb601BWG/Ite11HRAZvJg0oTlLG7kT8@6g193vS02eB9EyJ0kbZ2dnyXsbT6xneVIQupZaeDGZXmgF7cXkQlNKL45HSqEhvpi0@FIte9xqNlrkyZMPXrVfpfnJCR1RTAGB7T7mlRyfqJTJ2VZBSxyX8atpUMJj8hKu4x7BPzW/7M6ZdTR3ekC3SZ4kmk38Xilf5IHtJVvwp5ziOVyMZzTqYl3car16lW7oejCZEsuyRn63C7c7IClVTR8SaGq3oRGxCBJp0jdFIlz54aRHJjtmvz/e06fW@F6wLRbFkqjOMabNhx@@H17V958@JeQpefr05cEKNtbKZFKC0KDmSeT4AKS97IRU2no@gd89@8vP1i6yZ0/am3/5yVAy1/D1GF9fvXiI5kMlf2tt7dadO7lcVlVVZn7y4ZNf3NnZyd3N5p808ls5QV7b/Is/X1tT1U1VWmv5vtJKNo6PP@BVOceLf/n9ZPvJky/6fl37bx@/qiv4KMLjhBRJGS@NKGDEZwluheTz5E2vxMuEAldiSn/tROR@tkaU@lbxf3zz8YtEkKir0vsevIPEi0ShlGBGMIBNi2wniXpiE4MVLhJTqVargbH4P/4DxK@/C3DQZ7oJj3o@glWYJupCjUY5T9QLYFBUFdL9fz7@eC6HwM@AldSgRQqlyG0bGGKjweeKKr/VgmuDXpscHjIkyJIUhXOCQWC6RCndVm6jxQILvBx44ZBQM4Fffny8TcRnBxnoEzLie/U16e6mAJc4khRFbSrKbWC/wq2NWk2AfoU2W03L38YDINO0N@y7gUvM2@8vXIn3/6dcS8FU3/@feR2QXcswPTfLJQpr28/v1utQXq2ubdQz9AobGW1vxRLvutvAa44GY89y8ROS1Qf4MZQ6L5dUPpvNbh@0IQqZTBCFwmQithEEYV@iTrBLbBPmgs05dGS0CFcdOUGLxO4sVmSdhSPPkw1oI63nq8Ml9vD6q//0V9/@q2/S37fp/V/whCana/WkDQh0As2lDtd2pWLU63zd48@aaK8DjcmVUqUktS@aqY1GvXUAYu0758m8liSH9jQLhVBV0kw3GzR@nSZbD5NHez0xc64zl/q8W@jBAlMHeIeYIomonHPlirFGyJVwXCJaVSQ0TuotAQcma0JDKeRbAovV2IbK4dVimW@3EsL6FDiR2qqrefUx2a6ziwzWfeJibjS1EBUkzG99VraZz8xWn3dK1KNo9VmYzxsuzFOZSzQaUsukfUU9yuj2WmWtVClUVKldX31VZzHwokFN03ziJ04S8VUlIR1G@EzElDnn9my@JuJqIREBk4W4rwkHdQVMYzIJ/6q6lC3T6tIKCl8NTWqbJ1WgD1UT1H6blxVobdvtWHjfgmsNfvQPV2zF5xp1CZ1pkOvXGqkoG6om5W8V9lTseq9entCoZyhnFFr1jIgcUhCvhOGgLyFGp9N5aXRAMtH1jm7oSqCP9Yk@1YPOuDPpBMbYwC8Dkyco3rVDNHiam3dLboQVUUhoeWU9cRvLpqll/Mgu6CalklZWtaKiFQtaUVZLea1U1oo5rVgEgFpR1crlnKpqhaJWKGmFglYo44eMIUwBwmgIoZjXyhqXeNVYIweMv01IJrqamddeT0XK0fCiBhdvQXAnCRCcxsZxlkv8M1x1RVXIBnSOMjxAIqRGotIflHBXt8Z@liMJEPbOWq82Gq82yHxtCWGe4SW2t1sZ4eKiAeZqNfxv1mNjlV7MBEVtXWQym8/qIAM9qzcyAPJZCFIUCAUqtuuktUm94tTC5EL/zRZp9cE7M/L7SDMCzcULyEVms7FZc3fpLdLmKbQgmc2FrG9vU1rbhlj1dWAD6UxmXRDWGgC7EfZQEBgpMiwjQGqRFAgwZ2c/5002N4HJXGxe1C8amxcXm5vw36TPi/ANrheb1/7JnJssuNvUNruWBp0LcNFCPtVsSPWm1Ax5VQvsolRHF1FqgqEObwjX0NRSC3tHlH7E1r/Mv5idPWMXzHJLhFxziQ2ykcBDjbTEBpd4fvnp/4Z38/LTH6IkS@BnVrjEGSFcQtooE@pGX2UQ5x465CG7HDDjHVnRBR3qD9HRYQ8H9WNJei6SikCV5JRSKqRF7P7bbq@Nu0ZF8hyCQrC9vgmNKOK9hFdLBb6dUaYqSWzyhSJlt79w7Uomk//quVouJpkOjtsen/u@/3Aul7N8QuCqKiuCcl5nh9SyU8R/Ydn1r35h1cUlzssEcZQiDC9cAsgoIUmgO3KJ@uYQ1@DhFzgE/JTaSe0D4emOsOsOR3pAlXQcwQNRoba/VyuX66g8metPaNvZuLsBTwX@e2tQCNLsQdBmr2YMQTBv9rS82kRd9R0ddHZgdELnBf4evMQfOTLwd/ACf@ToJf4OAvyRhx38Hb3A304Hf0dD/N15gb@HL/H3tI@/5luaplT5df2kO@nCf/JyfbJ@RnGVUcrKxfqEZzhLbNWbbwE6/WSVbCffatCxoHy51UDfFni8FXjTSvhtCX/qZ3GJpGkgxk0jxatbKp@usiojJKXlyum32EBMhbxF9Fq52qmp1TB6HLXmuLFNtPzoC38ptqe2oqZx@EMr511P0InlwwMcMlpZcb3kT7/xySfJWi0pJOlp7DlwEzoYqEMDgRVi5qpWTXkLVJhXgllhuUuZ6bfooFvlLUKwTG/hmKXrpYZpy0l22U4RaTy2upLlSvgtW6s/0nFZn8Syj4et6R5zk05M50QynfFQemmN9NFI8k3DMwM8gQ1oYhKcQKhZPBEpqasHuvTSdUwc3JICd2gjxCQ7UDjFS3y60m6zKO025KpqZbAM4bgWK0XK2sxDKVO26aQ8c@SlRCWdrmv0nFJByGk5KH0@jWcN1/ORo1IGu5J@CyqPiCb7TFUCiFLhEjWyrqwrsi0bstJROmCwiOwReSAPlC6ov22FyCaRp/KUyENX6YLJhJ8MJkvuEblPZEd2ICD4giloywGaevDqw68HgDz4WbgwqqPIBoGEbFSS6QeiEDyYztvknYHrB9lRk2uQJOGfm8@fP8c5C7FgtfBzAQ3@@fOmtNFSyyUiImMQ243nzWSLb/J4mKxazpHO1FxrPudBvJN5Vt/oQqCcjWSrmpCaTSmkUjVHCf/iot3ee3S33ZZQzmgSs57ZzkAfub1dgz4zfG0l6tWtZoV2w1FXnJA2t5p1TUBzIQMdqgpu5L4JVZKVMp/zmgGGd32NIqD1/PQ5aJOpU9QpT0/gdRoZ3m/Co820Teotnb7fnLNSA1wYVpLeXwJhwQC5drxpLDnCH1Tyf66/9S/r//ApSacarXTq7GIzRa90iqRJKp1On12cXYTPejqVCi2pTfihA9gx0tlFHY000BmYGql0K31xwdzgmUpDcPxBlM06jToLdkYSLMnwFz6ohYCBpGYuLFep1HyYWRAoBYRg0XCWajFU7JBOhVcT@PxzfnPTM86bVcrsc3KZJPjnVX02bdNsTmQ5Daw7PO1acMi6fk7HuNNVAz8lt95pKK2/@D490XwrTQPlc9WqskGYRc2p1WoushVL1WopsqynUuXrV13eUgqgiOZy6XS1CpatCKwMVojbIK8ypEaa8Gzdvs0SKann5xFMLVfIyDhdVq1GKeUhWdPXDdrgQT89239MTwMHjpFPEGQM4YB/SqZfEzjR7VSSr/C3b6fC78Vu7aRv31bL8vl57DIagZOy4NRudy2v3UZ37fycb/N0pqWcB7tcOj9X5HJGSRJgy6lH@NFPZOCCQm6pdZossmc1V0Suff0q4EAdlIl1x9Ukn6zyiTNaCKVUZJyMp84JaNHA1f2ziwStRpLLp1PABNMgil8k8Ochv6S9iJbPp6s5WU6cXfAssFIus9BpkiukSply@KutpesgZrIfyspaJrdR3NgGVQR//mTZhRy1embWlIvamVnB78hcVI3we4q4Rdm8fVsrA15KcoLcHeNBCdkmF7LjGogcKLHCo8klkxly6zaH@7e9ZKW6TWtVKeVJIllljkIS2DopAYIldSOvlBAjnNXDgwdA7OIUisQ1ssap9I0PrsxQu4aOCS4RM78b/1wXLtIlHdLHi/RRsycWselFbML86dMw4kAuu0Lf2Erj4hW7mPHFJjS0vMbINkkejA0LBxWfPNjZ3TvKqpsCSaj3dnaz6uHTOwkFrfmZnXpraD/Y27n7@ClEePJgb@dw75399/aePgF3n5zOrrjriDqQuCOZMy2xn5L3uY@8l7pp6ubYNNun4/HpC/KRZbUtqG97DGVz@x7xzTYUaaTPileF27B8/aOPdG9EL3L5vS9ffu@XLn//G5e//@XL3//2Tz/99pfh/gHc32Dvb/xxOY/Pn3766394@Xu/D47/Be4/g/uzn3762x@zm9p/BPd/nXP7UXjPhWM3B7C@9tNPv/n9n3769e/A/bvh/Z3r9699tvz@9pdW3xjvm394c5hv/Ae4/4jBisJ@4/eYG76vhf89Fu7r37n8zf/I/n8R/tD4@5e/@SN8hJZf/c5f/NfLT/6zqpb@4t9dfumbl1/65PJLX7380r9WL3/73yny/OMPL7/9J3/zp3/0N3/6b@j/B/T5R2/yv/zOr/71//7X/8df/2l4fwb3fwTTZ3/9n6EN//2ffA//3/yTv/@z7@H/f/2Dv/@Tb/391/4tNfwOM/zj7/4xe/74ky//@Eu/8eNPPl3x/PKNz0/fwP3TfwaXN8/nm8B5k3J9XpdPf678/FOwMUsFaAAo95cvf/srQLy/SRLk8ss/wM0ScK/4/0BVaJgfMNv/Dwzq9TKjjwwmuL91@eVvkA8QS/8LYAn@5IMPoGv6IOz9P/jggxCDX0U/cP@AOrJrMSLzjHxnPl8ls3BQDd8lpPH8eQsnixdAU8tPP/2N71NbwqzU6UQgdvkltZTZAO1oo1wOu/1wjhCifCWGmliEkC9pjuNUw5S/itxrIZGvIt@7/N7Hl9//15ff@53L730NO30hV87uZAXlNROtEDD/BuEwYOFNwmFASL6doUOlQgbM5rmEu3i2zwmpQjm0ktacBTelXm@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@gRXmp2RUFaWw@9IXnA6hMnJGnd2rocr0dZ1cgFOBQ5D0DRrG5/7wswi1tbX17lEndf4x3TuPSNJxDuu0PWE0PaodlUhfKHMo7NJF1cyLD7EvQFZjpqrWExy@fH3Ezm5mODWk/SbvYQlRG5l2L29vUFuAVrpe85tQpftCRnNzbkJhsbNTIZXIdG6C7YNisIMhcY9I4ka/sE9QckNeuEnumf5WS5LGV8WXmItgd7k8ePHYX6pw7Mal4F2qGoK2nHedTweQ3Szi2scsllRzIrZbPgW6Zs6iKFBpL7hW1xH1JN5NVAplvBjnY4xQLxwr169AtrgEBeVfRxOpkZSU3Ml6kkoGUxwQZ0@zHLsDAPbnkbrdtVcmWMDGEQp5AhJUYpA9ZngAtUU0HiaY6vcGHlFVyqplkpJGhJqTExBMAamoCCnYiuB6W4lki8uWCFn81YcmmRTCLj4Il6Cy/KXKuXTkefuY7L7@OHDvUdHo1YLOhv6cVizPfJcw/T9FPrtPLrLyFctF9KJRgPLflRRkXNyexUZyTizf/dg/7BCGMbCqkvRclTpuoUQL2WFS4xG728mPJzG8EweP4nk8of4rMxQkVLLGkRN1LmEYaJaBnSKf7ir5MDsI/k@9Pt33AlJyVmezyoF1KTTOA0P2flFd0zwyEN2zgJwB1wtKUJ5Mef1M2FuIg8d6uRA5ZhBUKiBaOVSZCgyg1IsYIDH7KNhGlc/3DsCyEePiaLKIjlwOxZkqv4BmYiEAA84cIemmxUuaGzkSEfW0MUQds02nX4wWMcPsfJNmZ9D0HpDzuJP1TR4KrlCVskXW2tr9pmAcJqUZM5wLegFWM8ExMnbcBHubY68DU5wCReEc0emQ8KZjv3HVUa8uIOXpCD3h4HHK3ngC2kOp35CeNxo/qoi1qGhLU6icom1Dz8MSL2@9@iusH8PBywmAxKtJBWsrjgQKeV0x55JffuEdK33LNxdIHYtf2TrU2jFgLCNOmAkwBnuxMXFRQ9g7t8jal2lVha3i88Lg7p0wHwx0TkCHLrHJW5HYzRc8XalUnul5IqQt0rllaaqHDhwGxKXsHprQG50VdCGxH68U8spckZhA/Aph6R5nq/6kClNK0kbXELheXhpmsbRFkS4iskRulbslVyrCSGTzyl0qRiHB8Hrk5oaX2HYya1ZWE1mYdEHPEg/8Igc@RWZX2iL@gUoCi6epp8EjcYF5du3NRyp0nJyXHZCUUMuoE7XtZxGK@me6QRIZwR9W4lcMZyWhHK2EpxtBqRbA3OiiQWn6bLF6PhZdp@MIWQhByzxtKIqbIoqp@YSPMHQyCi1kswlGgngAVyj1aj9f/9rNbjW5F/uH9DSaNS4CbDS@Tt0xjD0TRZ@HPfQfTz7P348nLfe@B8@dh8@docu/KHLfIicvjr7V6sL1pv/IYtFLlutQo5x7hAoVQaBJQ/Wf/z2x//wm//pH37rqyJeoS12@Mdvf4u5/@6v4/Nb3/6Hb/3SP3zrt6jLr/3D7/6b0Osff/cPyF3gBdOXOpLo5dc/ufz0jy9/@NnlJ9@9/OGfonX@/@m/D70@@dbMEczocuX/LfK3v/Z//t13v/o3n338d9/67O9@509@/PHX1ZLy449/5e9@57O/@bOvEbD/5Edf@fHHX/vbX/nkxx//MoSb///kR1@NvL4UO4IZXK7/wR3gcv9iLuSIuLCCrhXYDI@irNPF/g2lnGvtAVNpkNZmdEplHUJvsl14BI8ZqfFY1VJgMTe@7pt2T8Ql9DV@c1TXZJXfDI@6rpP3TAeZdhi/3q11XYN@r7raFS38bjjuN2Pxcjm@6jp4IF0tmlaHrj191q@d0n3kVbPWF/HoE8/RbYjecbtT0Q@mIJMZru16tSRomEkQa9@zXJvSC5h3uq6DIqNTM0GrwQH9LU3LVaB84sgdban5okCEhiKDnIe3Usp2oePxtqDDq6jZNXOrWKx0RcM2dW8rX8mjtxEvo9jKy5W@@MHDB/eDYHQAIorpB1u5MkTA48PwoJ@tUiWfhzbM85kGTbGFH@JlPbqwtgYdoKl3BXjjKgtfUEutCk2/VksmtzRFFZSKJpe4sLAzhDlVR8gphS25EsyjkezZluN6WZ7D74XGtYAVOFDqOTm3KcGbQN3jkg@QX@pkx@yb2AHQmlM2pRHSBBghqA7GDhjzm1IHjBYYy5uSBcZxXVPkTWkMRqOeU8DVYFSCtUGsbg3SxJJlMNtZJJfsQDkLO/SK4zrmBVfJ6lnrjNZcpdfrXWycZWYWTj8TmA3q9ELQs52z2FoV5sJVyDgrWDNPcNF7QCJn4QqXCq/mS3y1UZ3ZiwW@2rrgtodm19LxW89N@ex6rAJIWgxqAhJqEu6i4rluUOmYPdczZwE1pRAFZBm6HiDHX8TJNWVM8ex6coW5QJOzGfZirHVs1zgOU6LfPlyWVi7PX3BGiA7P7F6whLKVbOTIolLiwMrCaks8e8YlNg7e0@p1oM6zXFHN5XN5VSsU8kUVpMpyrpAvAXHIBTmvqsAicuVSuXgBbVOSXiXox9PI7lnUZiv0@PyUXmGHSjZaJP3qkWWflTSBMZlUugpSSOIVl7h18J5ar68e3EqBhP6eKtRrWr4MJg1NqkZlFVUVVE3QFEHR8P8ag4r/Nw@vwl/FJ8TSVO4Ij9x5BMIx6AUOeYCnhgQuOXJdulnrjmmsCLE70OnxPrue6/v/hDB3dOeYed212Pmusdd9HT8y5g@tYLAixNPR0HJ83PH1zwVhb9iBDCJPZwHuwMOzXXdZgCJ5@gQeB/vv3D@K38tL/TA@MR2Qw45MhxhHezu797kCufP40d0rr3wILk8e7N07iq1F5htFzccgfnHvwYOr1vCVe/z0oDd2Pby5e4@f5maP2An3uHE5uBYDxc4USPhAK4pMqAGQNdDFI4PC4fa627kyuR0a84WZUUbj@2wDn@XHO/DYHtAKdxTt6tMJMvqOSfCjTGaXjnvSAwTD4QKlWOa4EXHcU1KUSde1bR0/ft5bA8eB7pOOaaL2a9tIiZj0qevZ3VOra66BqAlplBX80DRmgrsPQIZjY4AJgPKBx8528bPkuDygY49NMh6RlY7wQic0elZ/APLEqRsF4Dq6TuD@vBfEN@ev4GaHgKVB3a752NeDcwlu5zEOayRKPL/L8/f14jOCItIgW8pqFYcP8nwfJ4xtP@g2NsagN62t5UpEbcq7Ml1kNdUVqdqpEaVwXne3UVHfaJv9WsXPF5Qt7HZrcmY74fr3zVKV53UnC1wyW/FxhMKxnhGjCmIQqtd@cYOQpnleKqFatutputWnVFX52@/@4Cd//q3Lr3x2@cPfQvGO3HU9Q8fV4KjYEqqmhvqtSMdV1HIpXyprailbKpdyeaWQz2cVNasUS8Uy5E9WSkqhlC8r2VKuDHJZrgy@@XIx1I4laYPs2DgclmUasLRRAfCOgR9b3qRDNOKgziXYIhPyMqWnSUKP7WPCmxCHJztO37QBBo6sBXQr6YZVg/6aKDLRigQg68QgiXv3duV793j@Dlpw9d2uzPNdtORLsly8w/Mm9dktoejJuyxOCU8Q5ANmkeU7UHVjBgAPzef5AVr2CjjdwfMWWnZ37t3DdHpoUTE@BDtmPsxiR5YiBHPQAuo6BfAihgbBdlg6OZrRPbRgkuhzj/nsgh/PvxNlB30OWDAG4H5U0p0dnt9nlp0d9Nmlxc6zjH4BLTv04nkPLNCueL4Phr4HLZrnO2DE1sXzBpiMqQ5u@IFrPG/dCXSenzL0IIJ4fkJD68Yxz7cjd0zmvTA3ecRuhVoUVuptainjj@fVKNMYTIstGs/nYksOynb//nv6IOiafXZNPfY2oKT37wNNT8Z79zrvvNPp9zvedGfvnQP02t29D5LMdOx1@p0wYqcNlwuxdu@r@vFwevWCUu@32xXdXur1hXY7pztXvNrTtok5hFgvIGfh1ceEhu1d8Nq9397Wl60bogDbyFiG8O7gdWcI7zt6h3lFF/Wi70mnw1ehGYCW0kxxqFjh0h9snsfAqJ3sUDc8t4r2SY3IdFH6tFGQW1XqQYagGcnVC/TvpfCp4@h1@mzamNTkVm1SK6ps1KqX4psTNW/x2bXhllLOV9b0LUXNZSYV3AXv9pIkKShbJKXc3nhJUo/SWyroR2t8c2tL4BtKa6tQfIZcrYKPLVUpVXKyStLMqhUrEEdOyoTgI90otraK@coscrGY0SW1UiyCzAf4CUBy6OB4cZukUqemfpxOY9bpgCOUhxacTGmhrWovNclOaiyTZJquTmpKlR1STOQr0FKpLp58PzbwhBTCgPYB4AQUJFxxluKVcomHPEgSLi3EYTCGnLOcXLo4O/PPzpoXMauUwDQb8n3/i0fHR0cfALcCUWTKRsrq4WDpE/aB@WiV@Dv3d8X9x5END7UX76FU7HriLvK4BR8mHkdOR6AjifehPwf9OHKDOIHn2uIeXUYNonXkEZ0sI4YHz4pH9xfgHA7cU5YyRPKrKL3peP4AnvlvdYleq4NJ75IUzRXR06dUkmjX67V2bWgOR8EUihjF@gKhB@LPwOz7LO/0GyT4hXYa/aznucPQo12TL6DLmyQmgkB2QLAbe1mA2K4RQXk@dLvP1YxRxVXl5E7tDoKptuHdAQ3f9DzX40FB5au9Lac2dny9Zz4xPTxUYf/xOkg4eCZJqkfM9Dpp7mHoXVSoLoS6R5xZHh@NhyldqHfSi044wRA7IJpSX4yKf4YD7JBznr@o9mok9QyCvgC7t05SXfFOeitXBYzdIe00OMnPe897RCWFXJXqPymEBU2QYgoxoKdr9S@AYMZAH5NKBXITVvkxQMXEADDUBvXR0yPromrUbJISyCRNcZSr9msNjH6Oj00BJAtBaJy3cH7gfVQKXoyh86xDc69OE3rNH3foZ2CI3FFUuVCdgJtSzFUHUN/6s0nVq43Gnlm1wRrOKBBaYr0KuAUUApiX56nLr3yc3hTyNeZWpaDOUd5oi@3apOrgAZ5AKTWtBh6ZRk7O5ksg0uSLWRAh1EJWKWS1bC4rFNEV5IdsPguOoH@BVJSyUzwhfFaeyKKSVUwlm5KfW93n6exxSgY8UOSls4G754yHBF2gypBaqR3eejqjbgCKui7RNwVKvMBkqlguwP2AjKzsgEI6MHWbRUgLRNtI2espDLR@NB7tNVqVyt5k9EXwSgkvtgqZopx5mU5XU2vpmm@@oLMvdywgEB2Qi5yJFn@0BjQdzroQfzxsQK2DSSmqlUajg2UtyllN1qCYVvu8v8nX@VZWXisoUGcXdHBdIYyzzM8zgOTEzdxGbVQQbBPqUCmrVY5ueUiQO96YTnxoJVUoS/mNvMwmGxgIbhSySMQtSTWjPS3JVDJZVJPJmTadTlZxWneNn82zUR2brslNJYFlk@RtNV/Y4kEA5Ct8WeUh2IzjYi6JHOV8g@zqpq97OCHD4RgFyYGOfsZdnF1s1rmJyO0NLdvSsyDDGvg9Ncs4Frl7rtfNko7VJz09wLYscjtQ2v2KyB2CgmdSU2MPz9QnLD49TgSjtUKAFTpbFQymAxO0IJGb0sm7QLzuCrVE8B0ltRiCvMUd4mkUm@oz/BWfPdx5jL972wncSkG23wK/MriXnj18@vjp43v0xIHZluDPc21zRKL7JSZiu5qo0sFzXOcAyWDRKuTNr22czSbSGm6qJxlREOv0uIZtlkozPDhIWiPk827oyGzWn7F3E/dUAmiOHujdIC26ztq0UD8n7@kgUG6RJFS57g0bqqq1GmoRxBLouhoyC6qqShVy0U7QHcJ1oO/JGWR6M1PHQxm@QKZTPSNERb9N6v3MuqxOEydtvlDW6AkC7boiH5O15O0N/FK1QBInx2t1dSOTfFLRMsm7SS2XOEk11@sZZZqUyEZGnfZwpReuLZKSEE41N25pG8mnmUqpn60oGXyq8KwkibCW2G5nt9Nln6OUTBILCF4r79R2@gc74dwG2dmtl9RpeJhE4lmbLxXDLDbXAWVq5tn2Qvw6yELPcCb0Sr2Rn@PaxnXkyWoycZYkieRF8qKRbHGJbXrshcqOvSCJ@OALXBgXriLQcgWSTpB0aCuWE34qTVdVhNP4byW3E0mcLSe@/wqImtYFbdrRIQJfeK4Co0k4buTgjgMcyAVRKp/HueCE9Hzkf6iWtIf7j5273j2TSzTXztdcnOcnVZ6B5Mkr590vgv4KNZYkzVpiUsuFk6lKvS4omyoeF1YkFRACekpBkM/rjJvVqUdBBZ/Lr3wnN9ksgV2VFbCraj6j1uvKBoihidHlpz8MvCk523tv5wFJ4tTsT/78@2rxJ3/@B3QRevKCTteqWjEBIdGoFIqJs7PR2RkIgRfML59oJa4trGsBmiRFLxc3xGqFSKVSeUNsS4lww2BKKSrphC8kwm0JhbyQSimSmt7QSnIafM7DI5lSqlwCa7RogjrxhTyfTuwdWHlV2d7cgpJtaTm1ugbVqsSnmZD4t2n65QSXKD18fk4IWIx6t9@3VGqSpLAdvRLI5ithE95Qw6@ENfK8VsfVgQoehBLNwG/gcQq4ICZZz0gbSQK6Nqk3LqoXrQydxqdDHs82nOYVZDTXcP/totOGAz9zw6c/06RW6uCDNbKZGx/5fGojLUndLu13cAmFINQTrNW1TZKvA71sSJDLjWjWnf0EoZm@/Mpvq2rhJ3/@a@ft8/YHqqqWy@WCoiZ@9rPNsTP2zW79ZxDxSXT4HRCRYXWRWI/cY9PxxXjMgXZ2loM7JS0nHqsg7FhDK4wVG0SD5xJjB/UxFj4aucAxCgIyqdV3zC4dseBOUKKm1dpmx811UzTYBgGFJEv1OXq@VbrKcZGuw/Q1r29kKQyygUcgN1pp7ox7G71APiOg81W5t2egwGEIEplrtH177I3ovuUUjae0suQ2RIEU3saj/NYgdJqE/bYAnBj66mtRWZZ9ijUqcxM8rRsPBgRxhHsbooRHtttTQveN0pCWA7KCiEFoPqlHtwFptyBtm0VoU9cULT0LkCUsdyySA2oc9zZuX6VqHoidxNqEAFXgKW8DAqAMqRCw1SKbREuTMyuTqc5OHbzA02ZwH64eHYvHYTSE1gU0xZGrGA6cQH3E79IiXYQ1DHxvzjECwmCwFXE1UEAxOrWhQG8BOUzeGBTAOh1gDdGikdu3Z7mq1axumtASIfxja4QDtbQenOV5BWCRJn8LWCqIVJkMVvbbi2QHGM/Q7ALVCewgx@pcVMKj9YLj4P/GRIsUeaWqqEcVCxDWF2sVBqAMIiPaWR0aZLNGFLWYJnHmDci7QTNFD02Khyeak1ui@kHkeQE5/Fki@sQUMKuj@cHvkG7vmvb58DxGuE9ACRvTY1eDgc6YQfh5eZBZIDoyvf0gih3HgqJYNg3dszxQhenCu@g0wZSmpDHa7PRFmg@67U7NEdz8lk/ji8bC0ATeOp5uF6azRsVXw4UK9UeuQ4/DC5A14e5DoAjgUZDAIzcwWbbHzil@9y2sGxp5PkdQStB0kPIxx/R4P/oxeRoXV7B1PFM/jnCTJWZfJMawS9QySVFCc3CNhhODS9NINMMd0KAQxx3bHEKWDk2THh/gVySpD4LfuIPT3tJDC@hqcM@C7sfxpbsMwdKpdWxJR3jGt@D28JQBChyggKyIzY@tgQNlc2x3ie26x8S2jk02p5GaP1oQP6VRyILykwXMzm5AbAXFXlXL4kCYkmWh4C7Cq8iMpexc3LXUNH39rSlrqTbW6DntwSyoFds80Z05/NLrnJsdGsDRkxRrBJWHFNjFmOVCy2SHkiXxnMBkWgTcd1NpjtavD1EwpohzZaMUn@DT0W55MHIjzzwhOBjCYR8DTNNoh1nAVgylfZt2ALTtQcvC0w0DrwI1l4GceN2UAU0vZPAOuUU0lcOAkDIGZRkAGFj1tUXo4AdRsRx@0IWKEekEEfIVaJ3DLvjh6Wkh@WH8iLrRTM@anJE3WQvBYadD06oR1iwiS37Ogq0D6ZkWfQ08C5DDJTlZS/EZAJvh0zwDHce/Gp1RO0d5SYVch5QlCCFENUChooKOLAdPPp77cBuuE7mjA3fGs/mR6oHoT09PRXqQ59izRNPHj5n5rqPb0qhvgTjsSoE5HIWfe7YMaRTBnZkE9q1CcTQYbU1QqK2Vb0/Zm@N6fi1c0ppK9vwkdo4n@K2u/vAE9SvIcM@nBHXPot/zM1LhCltGf2orexbRXyVJT8VLXiAQQhDMJDvNGlkAlu0Yx9neabcaepzQBgnAoRbNyBGP1/Uiy9CPTNaoF4dwA@SjsVfHPqaLCQASz2YMZkmzEkYhp5E1tI8sXAnvmKdkx/P0aYr6pzE0EnBqSsUeMoVun/qAEboZcsbOerUmjWlrIfokjg6dWrxoCBh56v9t7@v300aSRf@OnqKDkwHZ4suxnQw2nsUGJ@w6JgdwMrmYYWUQmBlADMI2TMbndx7ivsd9lfMa9ynurY9uqSWE7STzcXZ/c/ZMLKTu6urq6u6q6qpq3LnuBcqJf/H7gr8v4PuCvy@CRlWzrUWbRTJ8dYfdQa5Hl35VEsEsVZk7TpIbfCHIIIeLPIPAksvQO3T97RaptqI3/4JxLCrGAJ6YAsGdVLb1w0Xroj3xnNvN9lZ2AMyeIELAiAPoVptoetvzn5H6o5vR1PVCr2D7IPFG4o2vuleSG5hXsI/@ABFjML2GmNh0MJbOTCwQyA4DBJTD4COKBqV5amju@5mm6SMwTisR0JgRa0lk2iR9yU/yHYhLTHomrA6orQHC936XAE34ItTM4asr1erwYeZCGVU2TbftwRK5FMl2EigZmSq81uzTIGlYpdMKTSA7iqvFaFfUdxiKVuST1s07Of46@k8/G/0@zIt47IlhecPYN/Spgv77IELI6UJUFYdFbVwBg@ymPXJmsHNVWD6VuzU0s5lVaga3g13wbofz7lVKG/yuyeND2RcSk0TBZ4VlsQhdXBZ5WvK8UCRlgvvVPFltqRhB1ucFBGDkYqs5stpCr7YoFnnhEIs11W41JBeE5IKrcOnFGiTbshpoT1W1veDwtEE6xciCBMDL8zYKYtA0ITz7xkH3jR@vx1PUqlSbwZpDXCB5CEVs5LNuO7b1loa0tmhFACAjrgDo8a3WBSO64OXT/i9/jWJSqjWKf0k24LUCGIyW4H2DdSCfyUgHBoE/sUX7AMzdxFbLSOTpqAD/l@P/EpZ6qf7Lr77MhUvmwy9zVuR/v8vLNlJWm6Ca9JHP7eCCbASWCt1k8dYFbTCwQ2hOE9orPCwKv4MFYELFWIMbI5QUKW73mhfIvsBTnNkDP5IUFaycsERJfYwXGitx7lGCbGpEUJq0W9AzLiYJc1/L0a@sDMHGKMRJ9bQiNimIpE@CsxKaE7MESymMxtPh5D4E6HSPJG@cRGS1eO4V4D/AwVIggUxkv0gRbcwHcSOKXF73W5TJSU4E4lORyuvYIIJ9UI4neLxuJZ57ImF9AxVNZNxK7cQ0wsnu5TFJqD4g500nKahlJdKZBFWFd5gDCyGFQfBo4nuFMKCMsqlSxFChwAvbMnRRjbOArkwGDilmdjb/Krf3rUG9m1hza9z6tm1tdosJAUuQPRl717Pb3k8D9@qmL0Zi@uPlorv85WchdncE5sTc/oZDG/N7xSyFYlHIq/g2R9cUSAS/o@BNTDOeUSbtpKALCjgM4KmgyxIE@SoUUCaMcKnYHCsuRKPCvDhu7bWLE1iEx61Jex/NGvOt4nwrv5XCF9/kTczzgzVT3da8DXS502bRpvHaBq0G75AUpUuPDj9hTzNC5oI57JAensLS4QVeLDQagqBPzHRLCqmMuwNlBRg2gKhf7GxU@6jZU3kLn6R6D5UyooaQb4colPgfPLyGzqMdFo9Y55h1H0DicRdIGJT0HnbZF9ustDsCe4SlYNce6EjgiKM5Bqe/n0o/Y8hrBQzuKvUFjWN4B7BAxRVP/WGnLhjGf1wPuz8dvxbbudzLfO5FXiMZXvyKCOYyL3aC7QqIpD5so5vPbn7HMI7d6ZL99WAzR1g7aQRoiVNUjt@DXubcOJOJY5RGI3bs8/D2B2d24/QyhlF3euQzenlNFEE17hrJBVqtez3r8pUBdHP8EvkC7zOhSwZg8uNfdEgcg6rTlzfdWQZaQUAhGw/nbCtxb4Z4NYdv@em7o5F7iwTrotGF6YGVxg7sccamKcIoIbEULqTvj6@9OU5ptBojQPsS72Xt@mSYwObXhZEhE4YxAlBkuNMam/QimEB73ZGNqlYmDgFoSKOAQgC61rvuOvfiYBASn4mDkB1T0Ri2GpmsOzNcmitjG1VbkOsCAtOoUDUNdxjg5ptqQzRqJ80PpXpFwPO7eu19tVwpi6OPovmmIo5r7z6SN654UzstV@oNgUGix7WzZr16dN6swYtEqQE1E/TBKJ19FJXv39UrjYao1UX17bvTKkAD8PXSWbNaaViienZ8el6unr22BEAQZ7WmOK2@rTahWLNmUauqmhHUE7UT8bZSP34DP0tH1dNq8yO1eFJtnmFjJ9BaSbwr1ZvV4/PTUl28O6@/qzUqAjtmlKuN49NS9W2lnIH2oU1ReV85a4rGm9LpaaSjtQ9nlToiH@rlUQWwLB3B9ogtUT/L1XrluIkdCp6OgXiA4KklGu8qx1V8qHxfge6U6h8tCbRR@Y9zKAQfRbn0tvQaOmekHqAKjMvxeb2CJ1FIicb5UaNZbZ43K@J1rVYmWjcq9ffV40pjXxintQYR7LxRsaCNZomaBhhALfgOz0fnjSrRrXrWrNTr5@@a1dqZCYP8oYI3pxyXoGqZCFw7494CkWr1jwgV6UADYIkPbyrwvo40JWqVkAoNoNpxUy8GDQIRm3o3xVnl9Wn1deXsuIKfawjmQ7VRMWHAqg0sADCx3Q8laPSceo3jBHjxIzCroTjXouEU1RNRKr@vIuayNHBAoyq5hch2/EbSPIMOtpqANsS7BR17rAtt/dVXNw46ha1Ke/Hyn3/@dFwrV0RCnRsmgg/nsOu8ihxM6d9gp/E/ws/QAUDPubwedDCzJ0rsfjUWqsbewMIcCSZGZ18Y95xVS9mNKmxsdDrvS51S/XWj0zGtx9QMofFQDUoFCsLaPaVM2UcMJ0MbGgqVhQLT/SBEqMNvUBzsOzNLsCMylWTqf0Ob68Qeg66YzfYcWQ1NIQhYiaWwB8/csQBgPVwayQqL8eRBkyT10O@hZAeqmFLgM90OvMaecyHXg38mvwY/eHPQXsDqzKJ0Njtw5owGKKiqGW6EDEz0j7TvgPZFkrznOD8NUjm9OWfSMzN4xxN6SMo6VHbujEaDlPlA9UtnEKmejtYnZNGoqdIPexxVwNoFMiafg0mSCTkumRn1LIX/dOb0x1TYsAUNDSXUFJngpUKU@oart3JtJCsbCkGi5kFGme9t6fvqB1Ryc9s7@5H3b/z3PLfQaRD9S2HDa1G9Nv150@YCMMHIsgkkGUp7Yzar1QGxjARKv/AtFLzCQnxHFe7VVw7t60ASEGSv7ZHeJu7Gs@FCxx7W4df10tuj85MTWDoR251Xuy/39g3/EPN7i/9@xHbIw5POcKewj4OcRp@0WXIMgg/NFM0dP2B/YuBsFgtiFIcaNHqJVjP/IigWEjirBMlSB9hdD5MrTNAMknAmdHkVmTOfGopfY2emZIBUqKsm9mZsL0jEt0FWIh6Qh6ajJY3aAv9B2P70V1Pc75BkIMli5PMKnGs84XUvgZXopK3vXk/4GASLZBKKj/lQ3KcB3mwl8gV5jEi/JG9rowiCLQ40zlcadqoJSDyNYiGkHkre3dDEO7LaSuWSzmLhzfeS3@Dxo3QXIOcB25uX5g0g44lfE3XgQNGVnW5JyG2MqsMjatXSgUALgimRorknVVXfzKrNBkIFw1rROhUGvO9bZaNNoiKc/FsS9G3mVDSFIpx9ybHyN3BuXHcklH1ljZW/lY1PMCzfZMxUu/XbMFSRj75VUJEzRKavogfB/xNpEgP/ADROgB5QS3OpeBQlCSrTCtRXIsrwVhkxNMtJQE391ccAzJ0@MFd@x6RlaEGuBEgCOTpL9eIjOZH0UzEEQCY30bNAm78916GbtWFnBtXpbwlTVkcbzKQ7nqaE3CvUVrECN73XtkjsspTdBn@YwiTDrNAaPIWq4m@suF3SrAeVKaLKi@degsGZypqa3cTzjGDCE5ciRfJqsgeclZOzTK0D8uBK23B6/vkTiKV3ay2Cm0JzOAqt/dKqpggFoA8Rn9V@UnihK7oj13Mi/it8o0KTfArQe9@S1w9KBwD0NEAXJ4TzvCfkzX7O/BY3iBFDJ8eHAJpIPSffC2yEjyUCwUEtt2YGSEvb6q2P/YKwv9WwP59wjAn9LAhVIsM@JhLDCV7NCDxDl1CLt/YSUB49rtvMYtnNhmuJW4ciedgsIetjtGXXdWcgOtrYb8DRGi7NjPggjQ7OxLueSW8Q2M@GM2mRUEI/NDOnO@SJFrjNcOwGoeYNQW6Yo80F@YO6NHbsiXQQGS7SeyIFzKt49BBZmNxaFlt5kToIvhwATcjJi4h4IPYwZRmVYoJKByyHKDj0fOUCZonL7RyIXDD9bt3ZT7j3owg06Tk9389LAwkv1CBVJ@Qx051z16euRxYNGAq0gPiUyLMh7dLu/nSLkjfs0S8lO4GAjq8Sga8ReoJRTz6/HZ9JJVRsKGBc2Tow314aBhOptC0drXzXq/z2LqESp3DdrVXGyPcqbBIXiYuJv6QU5P2pz5XoiE@8bvpPH/GJ789zis89nD3wBu3nUgRFhFFmRZvt6jpH@OF5xYehM@vpNlGQZHr2FM1vpPq4E@JFZTqUThRde@45S9AAutnhIkswOqm/u1eTzrE7sgdDd2iDnobhFQte8fBxSY84YIOZe@tRIDEnItIK9ZbBM1nD5aE2/pYeO/gzOOj05s40pR@BzGfLEiZZQC2GjvHxrNXfr4i/p9ETZ7/Ozm5Qya8jr4@/9q5AN91fW/dFPq4ynxYgALnAHUZOZ@iY3EGfx6JqyZ2mtOMOVeDyvgIajpciLWzt891ajL8FEtEBbwhjhczKkYfeCdTM1mLc6i2sHnl0zNw5rFtlB@NWvRS9tmxMkgmryHd4ClEQ@Vc5rSploOwt0KsDH5bryb398k/GHhD4CvTzL@K4JY4RaInry9kAazIpE9JnC3Ahd@YhrdG0EsMqNhzALjQKAe0solDDn5frqEGniiAUSaeFFa7EGZkCxQfzXaQ6sOR0lnTLeFIkTXIUQBGkhBe8rGVYR2dW3b9GbwePuDnMLoML07GEnNKQXkeqLlAJE@yFYE6vdZTZQ/XhGbO9/dhRixCwKAkYwkHLPJlKKMkFPbH5Ruc5HWu5M1iMExHqyVPJpDd3p8lHUm/t2hF7zh1H6665jkifIsxWhM1ys0ekLS7xcblvRPGJME2YYnSKDTyE6is9@2weJeKi2MH5VuwsH6DDOpoFZ7L@puKPd4/nPm6KNxhaqjYaf0oR7ujyte@/b3Wg4531K4iEyepVh1aMDi4ZnSU/aqAiZPKp9HgKEfdJ3CP06AHlsN0e0E4fn7VEjR7AKwcy9SnkMoT0RDd4e@zgujTtZ6AjKVOdT/mLlC9wLqwlHeXl05fosokfGCBKxU46sEOxBTcYrAgfUaxFP9VBt8A8rkTwdMg@u8rzSSLqE4xiHKRxh917W51lOt/eZ0gLHxJoFXzV@T2Q5Css1uosCMoKKWCKx5DC79HK2nT1@F59bV@gHEDg2vTZu8YjeJCmsDOm2AJs4B/9U2eBMnDQlKwZmlHhidChpQHmAmgpg5HD6ipKf8MZczw8pOQ0AgWCX6fwz5asgc7Rezmf2lhl0VtiEVOSm2ebianQqErAUPwbyS@nIou6pLgCAIcxhvrFPEBAJzHCHg8FRk5/HuK8EKJyjKBiMY/TEl6Sj1ngQxLzHYkqC@zsaiVycSW@1WGkY4GAYBFfJkAEZJb4IgEU2OhicdFKvIzvT1ACBGLF@0xxGAo5KmEa@iPHBKQ0eTkzWFFaeWHlJAfTx51dM/TR52/6@m1O@5qLfgX6@Bi20vno11e50NdQs9vb4aqhmkAPU2819BFIYeoI@6vC1/2fQS6BmgO5knAPNCUjJGVI3y9MYwhaJuhtmR89cYAmjkMlYyh4dBiXzpOqqNSvDgeshVzc73dnF0k6MkBP@K/urYrZUJjIyIvkxYQc7dm4ywohSawJ3OqxW6jpkjcFGk7I4wT0W6XTun3xvnlyoivB4nKpHI3Gzmw3l8shE1/qoQTKbwtNSUM3Gy6d7V@PRtnp7d9n7y@ztPZjBuqR5xaUBu3AkMCk8DLubMBxNogDFMXSaSDw2L1xUNe/7vf1gBY8ocTBg2Hjkuwr1hO0AQ19p5f3TQ6wPwk22H9iB7F//xT@7Lu1WdCUUNQxFNQG6l3cJNTpGZAHX/TR98s/qSJguDArbybYt8zi4SfcQTBOjAaLnEFNNAtJ9k@8cUYj1xIfMBXZ0wRZVCIVTk70CjkugieMSBR0MRoBh1nCuRmOgvMpD4vovI7g1MakonaUlz1GGtSdQWUxTSVaPyRgW4Eub2E3t9Db1xKJQcKUrvePAMt8CGg/qvTYnqa6RKdoYdjq5QwOngCjF3krVvcJFTHJJiZp9nBpJGo8upkf3eEkBV03SRZQkQE0vNSTNcV94iYuFvk@0jDHMCROdJfdo2rc7X/d0vh1y@LNvN9/3KpIQRU8sJ@1InJc2dctiHQGQDNQTj@gJ0ZX/iMN0/okEgjFAg6GPq2uO1ihgxUM43m3@PNtqlQqiWfTrS1RKh3BAyb6OSqJMr44OhJlzKKCv78pbu/u7vOaWzY/wcsj9fJOHAEMvtm3ezUrw0/4VsQAN9juSYt8li0@s/afdYoHh/tetlU6amezA3jiW5qyJfkDr2/KHtGP1g9@oUwmk33W/fTsm7t9/N0qt5PPLlvPpu3kYB@5DMhQup671XnaDtxHM7NLY4N3Ae0t@ZEqPdvDFK6yqlDpEcb27CdYXQpio@tlN@Rbj@NwaY3d6Drae2eCiVBAhVchHFFV3sAQ@bG9RHM8jE7XQQc82G8ofyv5gXJ9PltRhvuJqxXwT1U2CAEps944ABpPOJbQSW4Y4wfSw4nnTNACfkMyL3fPMGz4O5x3JP9mf5D3KGxepMRmTmxaYjORoD94p8LmhfksO8SbOriYf9tCcLSAbobCG5KgR/oDRS5GyG0YzygAEiGpcGgqPLkeX6LxWWl/GD4pw9e9gfGEbpdkEwkdMmGVjU/PJncwLJ@gxF3CeELhjHnM/cGCQkdqMdSYdqLijy@KQLbHjgBBy2MmSMGFJvGkDyrzmV9WvZFjbVBsJgFGstZfn9C8xxewFz2jmM58RJfCoFEKfuS3uDfuc/AuoY1fuP0AATpQYXUyR2EjyY0knnVQun6/l9RNQTGeev8k87Gvw9KZY8Wg@f8UGhPQpyc64Z5N6B2dY9JHpn9i6B@vaE0luCxF2/PJjKFVGV@P5sPpSJ55EYlw5PzW7ngm4YgSIIbDEdSF1RlGhgLMfHDrUBiyPiwcerwUPRe7zjNB5lnF6WBm@ORII0L2hxTM7V8jc9vMDhETxQ7MA4SU78rXt4cjD0k@VwlbB/bsEnMtUHJmMZzzuRnZ8zCvTgRjt@8jnSHI5HIezGfoysZ0Zg/GtiU2ztzmzF5WYdsCyWfezZjQw0lyTkjg5JNNx3VPIcw9kkNCFPG7Qp5DGL09Wspgcx5bHA0aDBpSNRVkggacBCF2Iko6v4bGKkLHgKs/YxB0lFcWb/80Ui6xtPKip5GEFHQB/qFptjJ1DNWCPnf8iZMwGFV/ZipekJWucaMd08EvrOSYzVu1TTUdeT4oYLnE9nF3GjgTO7Q5TUeGwYlJnmX3Be@LOJ8psQd7I8kbgPIv80H@AMQK5MgfQgluZKYLt88ym/EklXpy4cng@A19H0HhOeP74mdtZFV5Vk7h4GNKync@GfJiGdmhhkx7YMKMqJLnP0Doj@wB4Le8tZfIihcbqe@eZs3WDxeT9mbqYvLrxS8mYSKXZLXLpsWGPMxWK5acK7AzZq3QT@WV5slr6MXFJFzgYkJuXXx6L0kAiGRTrR@y7V@zgNDFhmluZi82mCChIUNMsve3l0Xw2RU0N8JYZDeMJ@amqQY/9V3eFLC30l8cQ35h8l/AQimVZKYHPWfWB1AUA0TXD6Bil321ndvZzu@AJjRwFumZc437bdq7vnQWIEp4qM7C1nPxS4gbQoS4W3j2PrxcQD@HgwnmgKYR9WRCC7mEymlO7Rg@W0GdDPMElAcqp5AEGOJi@mVsPHxEhd8SwHKqLGW0YNdBjftSuH967hjbsT1c16LRIcyR6GXAPiJkQk0jZMl4aznUVNMlScFmGXF85cAgIxAY3uyGtltM3ElaCmtmJrmPQjRGzYwwt290jq5M0dAMfSaFqeRTkT/87uV//@/azxvzjcPt7IcZ/J1v/Lyx92qDH@EBfr1Qv242DjcOsNje3cYyCzowPL787/8D9Q//DnDwy/IA/jncVbD2lhuH6SJV@XXjcA8e8tvb0O7//a//gj48Y40NM9s861iCENtXFDm2J8S78F1UsZesliaDZSWPCwvCYA9D0M3hBzpGLbZf5chMtyG9Km7Q/WfYn/v@KHKLJ8esObkKsSVD@VOAZMQVithAmkEqF4q@0Hw3lNsGMm@Apvjn88yeBxrAP6U7h9@k77rx3EOXoWesFsEAprhF0Of54TD3XcJ37ygklE/JvhIhUbWTa@2rF/vADu9cZz7shr0k1HQdd@1b5zKDfJhxetegU028kfvjLHsDLDnOb7/K9tG4nyU/7uyUIKWny8wvIAjKbCSgGJLTqSVmMALuGP7CM@YoAYH@xD@TUtk5QMqeOl22YYUzPEGRRrNcqdctPh7G7mQCUTpF/4IAj3lIZFoNLfL8YgI1a/WCSGz5Bbkc6bwmYvOOnGNl0pE0e8NSBlsQYKgPaB1U/cmUZgMKQqJaM4DARTJ2r9ex5beU8SShAs8t48mVM5oWE@QbBr3Bm8pAQpf0ZzFzLZT0EC0I6TQtdAhr7MxtUNGLCXqD@njQwhyvJuCzVtKNaXXxydqXZaVW3yue4JnWPU3fctO3MKIoJQTt@DwT5MKZCL0Yry1FNFXOnA4eqcU2DK15KgXWLEN/EAOPh6Xax7AE2R2KgASqBd2RXmX6sFmkCwOP3Docs8emRc4DZmwEwY@WKgGcVT3LoOyE7Wa4MVggztyJU0APZb5RDiMgiippy3BCAtDKZxU7LMFQH2pTh9FUhMKOWHJbmsB@SAIHxlIKIMHQ8XhTC3ywDd49fNASjpbQJ4GGl4SJLNUvkLJFBdVwFCipFjeOmhnbqVpd4Sfr6ctcQHRXGr5I5PLbL3Z2916@@hZjxp/I3saDwUoZ1AKmVzbAIIk6BUo2vi8WE8kEv8KEXqtNIvQ4sHgAh25dtyZhxY9Pi/mcBJZLEKxbSkzF1aW5kkAGEGdOBncE0FFSs0Qq9V2hhR1rX/TMX@G/hKVqM8OhqdkeDX@xmfTaOLzjgAhKczR2xu4Mj8dxYbYpswvm1YcthL/oZR23X3fwWir0dWW2h4ZOXReDEmbu9eBK544MW/tFEyYMEHw@WxZIg3rtcKQo6dQaViiLSoNDVYu@KCp4rdUeoFMubgko8zFwmGYwGdDL35aepjg7krAJYZ4HjFjFI0TNdVRnZ@LOiSsqZ@UoYjIT2tDz4WZ0z1YQ7mA/BPCV2glmPtK62wTqwpQYyF6rNcligz7pvnKBy2E54ApkeoyV7mJaL40qaq0muWGeuo8seeLFoZ/QLqgK44h4xcDM5x4mpYprVb1AgqiFUFqT/EXM8s9zdJIFOOmDjPMUeTlR0HxE3w49j/J5y8YSpvQopUIwkB6fSsQBRLtNLsEdyRVwROmxQmmseLT5/lRymcQ7R3mAfU3ViS057EtTAUWNc2YRnxbY/@rZsSXKFfjn5EPZQkH5qPQP7LefMGs9vnmJb74gqidqCIig0gxHPrfoM/UzhigBs@QsTl8SIIiLLxk2sB5J3kjBSvVE0p4ndSs0t9sBVyC72lIIV9ZROUkwawrZQJ5I5Z1MZzLXolToC2y8Wl1ptmRhNS3YxHX/xNZo8iRo1YfEpHwEiO0oiLQCEXD7k4Dh2QOdJG9b6i6Ksasn8TwdYllWqEBsP8kC2cM8u5Yy97HFtmSL7QKO4318QXx7L2/wpWVh5niAN55@GW@kH88c6X8L5qj8OdzxQnLHiwKuPcwdk@7MoRWJIjopqZ0bwzGXS9qDO73hYIj2ob72EzuRszQAtODRXWQ2xYPkc9i3NcuJSMV/2IruR@gktL27Z3xh53dk53cKuObSY9n5n9r59G/c@V3Z@d0C7jUxIy9FOxn@@tv1OBAJU@EXscOL4i4XM7@0p3uyp3sF3E1jhvkP72n6d@rpS9nTlwXMmMAHDpzC9X5uZkmk1DiuVgN3i4zKQJzCrIDxXGmi7oXXTFuiP7r2rooorYsvxv@VxP8Vrkb0VEey2lqMsq/Ls3rKwfIsWfKNeRhkxT3h/spQL72/csMK9BG5QfEiTYatmVRUQCC3@GNw2pQJ5Mdg9fU3n8fizGs75VbizLCaAs0aYd4MpjhLvlRYJWB9wow8R0vacbN@uvW/mAxj@ycZhQbI49De4j1DcifRVTAcK34tO6N1B2E3pM4RYhVJTkJ2LqO9fXZ5sn5Vo8QWkX0xXkngozZOl4wZqBzNA4hMRkCbjKyvtCp0zVXqBb@BvnOh@C7LHn8Rl34rufTbgqhLxWAdqWxp8JO8GOhp27u79@0BXCuDf3AC5iwof8@s@n/B4cKq@0epj9TpvHU8b0NLFmXoebq5jMAyIlymdA1lZgW8MmZyif4H7/3kU9uGlm0ZlBXPMI7flhtou7Avuz2nP7ga/vjTeOJOf5558@ub28Xyl3zCMFRy/pTJWQuV9400U6zma07MEpGkzWkta3MAAg3zSbaahA0hyXw@abYKhe22KXB@jjkfE58PBABIRJ14I7wnidws/OzhNJTswRCN7fXo6N@bY8w5kCw1sseXPVssCgL9r9N5S6A3mHzbBUICicgOk@rC6jk1TZPuhZFXTiR1yIWkpf/UuzobjKtsnxOJhEQJflbpQACNLX5R30LTIpNLW2wC8/GXYS9sKWGbjF9TptZDtUDy6fZO2ywAmT7QF2T4K3s05xPB1C@m7wnjzP1IAtw6j3mRw10kZ4YCFzSkD2gD9DtmSuYITrm4v9q6GvqutePDaAXg26HCIVppP7Zg6vuhOwAMpoJ75LqjUxxf1YIlqWGJV0FngkyIGNb8xh71/VFQ2YqH7FQZ4p1wHymHLFI7NDARQkhi9P2VLgimvsJmXWkp9uvjYQNgfEnuCiugdHyx0kqBFS6hNTSU04c2jWg9Hl5vzunEYzoRMGfLR4JyRAf8pr3fEN/X6jD6N/ZsiIYttrbloY2Mk4H5OSCH/7mcTLGJiuTk2t6FeeVDphlmriAX36d1KKdWX4LeK19iA7TuYAfw1lzVBdzNBpTd8GGkH4HyPdM5xKEMFtn7BLYjn70VU@f3pFCXTCLSUn6Mm3Zh7kbWnqGPcepVZLAVHXB67SG51Is2yyvB51c4zphzDPaAmc3uZBvifD6ERXwZ@DSTcEMOY7qURUmIGBjn5o9O4O6VJS7lD5lfR2KqLR5IG8rTf2UGicbXdE4Ba7E7xpZ4iWfuxBA@RBDgcAbkzbgVERvzf2bFtrm@u1AK@@mtCpaRLocGNb677rWOQO7Bfgbl1RPsIfo6vkKIYTvMAqsQ1FIrXYdxb5CfVjkbj6Q6Hcz90@lQqpVOB@WHTifJrbAwoQlB2r0Xpcve9Sw9s6/Gtj35e7breWm8cXs6N4wukPXgQCQrZ@Ukhlr5nzLTJYxDejMtZJ5@QSIHvjESiXCU6XGjIRrH9eq7pqBvBo1J1x2NHCkeSBmpNuvhHaHlYXeuxCaW8tSvsY1phQy6lFIce16DcOEe4uB2Ouj@3@mkPGfU10ZnI3iC/940356KJiUcbFYalA@xEVMUYWQwAJLUU0T84Gm5dtz8@K4CVByPDo0D9QcKHVK9g/lwPnIOD7L8l9958yWKAsupA1qgfJell1A3y5UPLt3eEv70hjeCPhUT6ui/MHNA3BreOPtQWactIdh33XmAYBbqI1AJLcsIqgp6ZRDkauWaKAi7h0c2IAgq5QEnlYeBIcP@UiRfJDNDj/T6lBluWd58IqXRJP/MYItJSyRvt5IxW394IBpvSkDL16e1o9IpZvx6V6ljGst1Y3E56ADToARL1zIkw185PM2dhIQK@jKXEmv0Y7jU9yQah999DL9b04165XUV8zmux5xJWhSfcoX8XfjTDfpUxX6hSyjo290qBmtQOTktvb4XC1TqVvY9@ooW5tiva5qqnb2uYQpKTJ25rkV3MgBNY9DBlmPIqz5j0x28qMN7FL1Vy0e18j00H4y4M9FGsTGcHo9q6rh2frZ@cZAuwvkwlA3DR/S8@e68aYRr@osVTBhapyyx0JYqbWpJn5SFuQ7@UalREZVTyniqfSJfl5EzVtAtsbR4UQEVlNZOxwPRxVKJClGMKUTjmulq1djlyL4E/fl67uxjHGjh0910sT93p/IBpxrm@C1wrGvq013PGZj7F8anuwS3XUwAQycOP93xYnUxSfJVNPOURFSfzCt4@0ibRoQY5Uq9@r5SVvRoaJ9DJYFo1WP11adXdzjrYtycRjHKP2PJ7DMxI5Ra2YTpC1GeISQJBFOGwfAz@l0NZuhVm6ZJDm/3L13c/GAX7g2vvcJu7vm@TxeJyEpzDNLSF8dI0vUYOUF1GL3L/sTu/mado74g7Pq9HQKxFrTSyxEmroD/Rr97By8MOaKX7nzujtOU1loNL9cKfcfJFPrsA4DJtb42foypGu3Jl5B7hWSP4i01zSi180n1mDf5Bkj9pXq99qERWQ1X@NKezdzb8@nvw5oip8YNniQFaRUTSDcB69qwJy4MWsXoAru5Py@5llYsphAPpSx1YXA5ndlRlyBMzOw2XUQY/PqqyUxEK7u3k39JsuHu8bvSLEynOlb64wgV9O4eOoU4Zy2hNJr/4dx1Cm3/SxJNZ8HfiWrr1zxK2X7vmhcIMM3K982o0ILkp3updcrjiy8j@Or2q3ctEAiphTXsIfH10Y5X3@5Z4fvD0Wid4OureItVeVlKlGtqaurfYp28XK80aqfvK6JcfV1tivel0/NKRGye4dnQjcMH2bKpmTPACyGAfnRCpTWc1BSILoZWUBwcn2NRsBuehqPNqO8bNC3RdzgcZDhPelzW0C2qfr6fiTtxYltSTQR6eSEuxVMUNFRL/ppE6xV9Cde5xdtBixKuPBD6NWlGTe9QTLr1JNEww8ES5G2L163iPZarBuGRtKHxKIXoG1AWAefb5uoidPXY2ttxtSUpIkeFINFcmRHzfLhzHih2q53bXu0cEOyruicRRLtWBhpNAbz7Meu63h@OGLT5MGKgFf7RVMOolhDlzIguv3pCQS4I67hENtyiWRA@DZNBb/9wlhRJtRbGmZq0KysKLGsPriePmaL6OWpwkLp4ikq8tTKBzYem8LE7Wh2y/Nr@JWeDS9DpLfp/099FYs/irfsuuYg/vrfWnOrfB8i8Z7hjl8LIplA9K1feVc7wShrxj8rHD7V6GU3CjejWIC9@jwyh74lNJlRPtznrBlZVgYtRNoq5q@6JAjnmSozcLswKHAkyltFOvAiOGhk8B7/Ag7x5OXRSrA7iaZkgc0YyTI0VGMwmYnWdp2Nm7hCC21nlB8qked/k5ep4PcVK3eUj6@Zj6mJ@@se2vb2m/mPbfxFXnyyzbCyS9irEiP8s1wjR/nqpDxEaYNYN0P2TfGX4zN93AMW/3wiS9esrx08Znf6oQXz11yD6/3c5e2TlnbjKo0dW3o2pPH9sy3txlR/b8su1jOubOle51xJRi91nsLO0u/21Iv1JK5Kye963KMUPGtr9/hq2P3PYyPL6@QNHhsi/Ru7PHDm2BX/@0KE19K@R@zNHjuzRXyfBoSEyMohkII3ih6p7FLtwO@xegXZNAhD@eJ8IiRbNCAqBNdNJPYJM5mMbQ3XyyxTCL9X1vpTR2GkHrd7SbC2Ux7pkrEJ7Xa/D3hvvS6fiba1cPYnz4FghkOf8YVN6mxR9n2yBJRc/kvdNnNFs1mHT8qOpKmKBoJOgP@YY3h87ydAvqaWKt8k2LNuPcbVmf1m/nvkI32fpuXs7czH@3MMbllSI99ieaxzo21FKZbxU@bR2XoeBrTc@Y6L33N9nYN3pWjqyifNLuP@GHfTVGhjlJH9x5Ukd7ZkshZjB561kvIO2ZuqkWJr@yLUD1OgtJrnn1yum33Ab6a9pI/24Nja/po3Nx7WR/Zo2stm4RtYsS@XK0flrkRWNN7UP8WXoi3eFF0Th7U7dmeNM1i1h4TUM6vw@vB5rOf/TrICRHcIfDX92RCo9aL@Xy9FPIJ3491joi5A2ODx8PDrDiUqh/KjhoQvQ/sDx@Zz9Im6MmCp8TPGb0nONLf6sdpYmA3zIEM932PuerbpJ3vMwSaC0ynvu9ayrn6dQalocI/4SZKZNrURO3buD4W1KYQdaDvHBOC@V74FCX4XKJMp3g8TzLTumbsGAxzYS@OF@TSO@l@tKO6GFSYknxJ0Xk/jNJL7vsYtl4O3cWnEAbreSiFGyrRiSCBELZkMHlE6nscqnJDNqsvDpDmRCAgWPd@vxiPEAjsU11ut5peR6X@ZVvg@aN9cSdGWcY@FFQk584Kuu0@aa@DF/IsgczSH2kOdIdHmEfpFE4d4jt0UolXO4tkhaeiTPWnLycVoga1piAUsQ/hu34D/aZTx2IjxugOMdw7VryugyYWPtPKLlfqQOVzdi5lIsjHC1OIkNT36B4PHUXrM5any9EoxIHCG1AD5jXzlOvI/zqWocWz9w6h9ZH/pKsQgmNp6e@1M7mbxbszbwHKP6/uUJSBULiG7GxSnquB2uQ42QIG3Hk3QBPXN9SSykxSulzLXTd0pZ5wLo6@eW3ImnSJUzd@J8AQn574NEjOHA8AT2/U3sFRuJppTx0TaJFWkSKyiAyD/jpuyEhOrX8nSYXdehwzpiSdQrpbJoNOvi5PzsWFTPGk18UTuhD6fVs0rMqc4yflj07U8RvKWo3Q5SPz565Q0D4g3xX2kVJm1eEVyOvfR0I2b3x/4BLn9gjhHtQ9FacZRF8TKesGqECg/TIL5iC2C3A0V82L4X0JBzYvwbcEE8Ne7niwe1AU0jmLjCu8akXriZOAvQQbyk@dg1qlXY4WUJ9@rfaKfUBITYnXK92BGzGMVJy2vseepKjM8YOCYh3QcfI1tINVPdkmGsnXdUIL/G7he4OckFIerhFBqeiP5WOoJVt3TcrJTF20rzTa3c8D9FnHkxTjcapbsa@qaF4JqR4PzkpTO4nkRjTCn0bdJ7JGSOnY0Na81Qrqb4kNdMd@QCjVYwotvfk2uj9Y5Lp6elo9OKJE00YG/hdKUeizl/O1N7fhXtAauxKuLWLwa7/SwZyf7yKhlFT4cQ6RYNRuRdSLeW9SJFkNCm8VDkOceLA9J@vLZsKkiMo5XLMB2C1DamgZlFDQO5QKS7Ip3XA9KfalHHdJ2OTJvOry1MjzRxbmmq2X5SWuN/QiD3I8MrczK6MhcXXJmj2Ep26qeQ6P0gxjJxuJPblfHgD8WFM4llqqNwkL@YuqPlYOTCMzwAxbM95yY7uR6NDNzye8N@PzwI@vPhN9t4I6bTvXIFYPP/AQ)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/j39vd)

This answer adds 4 Python versions (2.3.0 - 2.6.0), expanding on [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293) based on [this polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/139664#139664).

Python 2.3/2.4 build failed (buffer overflow), I use [these](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.3/rpms/redhat-9/python2.3-2.3-3pydotorg.i386.rpm) [rpms](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.4/rpms/mandrake-9.2/python2.4-2.4-1pydotorg.i586.rpm) instead (no installation, just unpack to a folder).
Python 2.5/2.6 build was fixed by removing sqlite-related stuff from setup.py.

Answer #5 is now considered to be Python 2.7.0 (tested on TIO with [2.7.16](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/oPAv/yC0oy8/OK/@vqlqUWFQOZAA)).

2.3.0 is the first version that treats CR as newline on all platforms, so the code goes to the Python 3 section.
Versions below 2.3.0 will require polyglotting with Python 1.
Changed `coding=utf8` to `coding=utf-8`, otherwise any Python2 version doesn't treat CR as newline.

[New modules](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/whatsnew/2.4.rst):

```
2.4  subprocess decimal collections cookielib
2.5  xml.etree sqlite3 ctypes functools runpy contextlib cProfile msilib spwd uuid hashlib _ast
2.6  future_builtins multiprocessing json io abc numbers fractions
2.7  argparse (same as Python 3.2) importlib (same as Python 3.1) sysconfig ttk (but Python 3.0 doesn't have sysconfig or ttk)

3.0  renamed:
     Old Name            New Name
     _winreg             winreg
     ConfigParser        configparser
     copy_reg            copyreg
     Queue               queue
     SocketServer        socketserver
     markupbase          _markupbase
     repr                reprlib
     test.test_support   test.support
     __builtin__         builtins
```

As mentioned in the [original Python polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/139664#139664), Python 2.7 cannot be added this way.
Also, for some reason (byproduct of [these](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tiosetup/blob/f07376a4/stage/780-installwithpip#L9)?) Python 2.7.16 on TIO [has a bunch of modules](https://tio.run/##JY47EoMwDER7TuFxBQ1FSm6QUzAGBNHgjyLJSTg9saHaXe0bSXToK8XHeRJjVGOfUdR5D4sJackeZLDNmtgEg9FYaxtjvhgZtmLmFFfcyLEAX5GOu3hnyFBU0ryDlvZzAWNwvGeanNSSgdjjVJyCaC@ZKLGWOGX0ilGacq4X8qhtN1SMjyplz4ihsuPYhu6a3M@H4uE3A@nNkRM5zz8) from 3.0, so I use `configparser` instead of `queue`
to make it consistent with the local Python 2.7.0 test.
2.7 is seprated from 2.6 with [`len(repr(.1))`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features).

The code:

```py
# coding=utf-8
try:import sys,inspect;exec("2?2");print(349)
except:
 a=9;b=2;e=not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394;i=1
 if~-e:print(e)  # if e!=1
 else:
  try:  #     2.4   2.5  2.6    3.0         3.1      3.2    3.3  3.4   3.5     3.6       3.7            3.8           3.9     3.11
   for(m)in'decimal/uuid/io/configparser/importlib/argparse/venv/enum/zipapp/secrets/contextvars/importlib.metadata/zoneinfo/tomllib/'.split("/"):__import__(m);i+=1
  except:print(i<5and(len(repr(.1))>3and i--434or 5)or i>5and i--419or 1)
sys .exit(0)
```

`eval`  `exec`, `+`  `--` for DOBELA. `exit`  `sys.exit` fixes `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` in Python ⩽ 2.4, space is for SNUSPi.

Answer (score 1):

## 439. Python 2.0.0, 18715 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyx" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf-8        @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_  22 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx 22                     @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]g[>++psg--.--._+._q]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>] (  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}'4o'6o@}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"$avdxddxdxz$x${print+191}$x";exit #?>\␍'''s'; @'␍[puts 59][exit]'''␍try:import sys,inspect;exec("2?2");print   (349)␍except: ␍ a=9;b=2;import inspect;e=not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394;i=1␍ if~-e:print (e)␍ else:␍  try:␍   for(m)in'decimal/uuid/io/configparser/importlib/argparse/venv/enum/zipapp/secrets/contextvars/importlib.metadata/zoneinfo/tomllib/'.split("/"):__import__(m);i+=1␍  except:print(i<5and(len(repr(.1))>3and i--434or 5)or i>5and i--419or 1)␍sys .exit(0)#sss1
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_ xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU )([])({}<(((((()( ) ())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>)(<><()>){({}[()])}{ #(((()()()()())()())(()()( ))( ()()())(()( ) ())(()()())(()()())( ()()() )(( )()( ))  (()()())(()()()) (()()()))((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`;a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# [']; print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or'\x161'=='a'and 68or 439));[exit];'"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';#wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!)>* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈ # ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→ X
♈♈ XX   X       XXX
♉♈  X X  XXXXXXXXX X
♈♈  X X   XXXXXXX
♈♉  X
♈  [``]````
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  #
♈  583nnn;
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#  
_+------+  
e|/0110@|  ;nnn383\          e/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e|/00011|101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
_|/1001 | 
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
_|/$001 | 
_+------+ 
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      7   83nnn;
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+    =x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +     +8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ? R`"12"`"420"
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ? R _`*` *
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.  0; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;ppp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{ Fenton,
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo if compiles uint64.low:21 else:424#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM#8""C""Ha7^ Exith,8,3:n"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya1/;b= 16|>o@,0,1*_eg=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   ni^ c;n  ppp s7*  \e|88let CrCa/3aig
 ; ;:在ｕ∸⫗
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({e63fd586-75d5-405c-8be3-9dbef9896092}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;: /889*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L39cyPJdSD448SU949IFtgNgEB94xsESDabPc1Rf4lkz4wHQKMLhQJQw0IVuqpAAk2yY0br0EmW7LVlyZZl2SPL6z355I31beyex7HybYS9EffLhmN/8h9A2Y67sB3Sf6B7L7OqAJAAu0deXziugKrKj5cvM19mvnwvv6qj@4Of/SyBF3ni2tO@7QYkMP2AdD3rxPREcmdKtnXLz6saxyHUjtcfD00n8CtcgiiE2LrTH@t9k/QsOzC9LPFNk3RM2z0Ff5WQzbEz9s1uHWwaIY55SvYdw@oCBhK4x6ZjvTQ98MsRcte0z4fnATHc4VB3uj4ZeZYTUN88IU90sPTGxjHRO37g6UZguQ54FRaiKC7YSoQ8dD3fBEyuYfq@i7jKCyCKTN7RIb6RbU6uYFYU8r5lel1CUzHyTJYWRSXvHd27d9VVI18QXIfcwxRe8cqRnXHg7gdX8efJTt90dKKKZVG96lkAOgWmXZJL8lWvIhSVGVjG1XhKZKfXsxyTPIS8XvUsE8P3Bd/wrFHAQVGSe5YHxayHxUkM3YFiw0LdIOZwFEyJwCqCbttxIftE98nYH@s2hXPGw47pRYB@oHuB5fTJqRUMSDCw/DgchfZHumEKXdO2hlZgdoltQSC3F2IB1E6XHJvTU9eDsg9xuo49hYCmYfUsDBKlAxDilQoGJsMz1KdQcZwAagnRiQ/JsM0IW5pLAPxdszPuE3ccjMYBgbR1LV/v2IC0MyVds6eP7SBLOuAHRULdTwemE9ZqQCcCiiOXpeqjMU2aOav8erdLZKjQkI5jk1hANZqsCtE0cCeuB1QDqChFITJawVkezQmUMJRZz62QvCyD/17sgqnVbd8NE7OYNPR0oNHSMkO8Tzy37@lDoEbXpDR9b/8J8Q3XAxvcCMsa1k1oDD0gm5skuffobpLU42IRvQ4XF1GNnEERJCJPcqLbY6gh8yXhQvl4cWgOiyy5lqyQJJBFlUkuR3LQfktEzQORFLkMBmAEqqbAXSBqieQUaG95ogGwpkLjLoAPNAiSk/PJLEbe8/S@ZZsMdR9RF7HtQBgVnnKOaNAstILGoPuu3WOgBk1FkWglUiiSYp4U4VkmZRWSgXHmoMXk4S7ADRjLkEZApGqQYlllyGaNAioxVsRd0tOHlj0NY6BRGCSvkCJghcwogF0tARZ4axreGtwlxLZ4zeMOBlAUA/0E0Au2dYy8zIzZGZavBC9pY0OifBMZM4veH2D0QFegaL5EihB9ASiSgyQA2dUSRA@eWh6SABBavgAZ0@AusMz5A9O2Q1QDH1HRHBRluCE3RaBPCYpLBjrLSOgi3GAHdqoC31SBSarA91TgVaoKZg2jBTgsvwKUfSHHohno/jFExOJRu7RQoC8ANAqWAvJIBQkHGKAkCZBfw4SSnIY1BxIPeYK0FAsEakVJIaUcKRUJ0LgsEygzBdKF1UoB9qxAehREBnVDgcqhQJoUKAEFkCpannBzBaBo6A9hNQgL5FJyECYHZihMpYA3hIMao0CUCsSpquVZrYW0qXnIb16j1VktQIkXwQ/opkJaVahmWIfVEvhj2BLQsIS1vZjMMkLoSAcoKWwfUD@BGFA8CsULsGBWi2GF1u3RQO9gZ8BCdnoYtIDtpoBkhKAyZg/eOaQmJAVKWcUWAslXoVZotHnBOxdHbyuApIHoza5FObqNvYoSU6iYpZX0I30UzMimFGiKRtNgELupzM0FTmsBtzT7ujGNPaFlZmPPmWtBQ1eVMucZIjmHrj6wYnfs2zMksSGn0qjME8ueuZWoW9fUuz3LH7yapTVHI@mYeuBYx7NY8vnsHFH1OY8Ceiw4FbV52MASoH/rD9A0y4taRJiRGxfQQpIVhSavY/bGTt8UyqW59FGfYOwF0BPN4iwzZ8/q96FXn@FRsjSbtGedOedpCm1Ngw4/ckTqYpyeBf39bWIMQF6JPcsMf7k8w6GpiGOqd1AMEEB@g26jjB1dz5qQzm2DdjOzBGqUTsbAGkXAlZXAc4VLI5mUCnN1g1LuZUmOWTZeLfEj13JSSZJMcxccdE5MJp3v2qEHfB@7NeyosepCR@xSMWPGUlNO1JWmgWiLUgF00zZKTx3T0LHLxg7MpB1whMcKRAKRgGBpuico8NJedCEan/a0HQ/lWxCLuqbnEYQFodjP0j7ZH3d888UYBa9ZunrQyZsgC/R0y44TQPsWPaASA7yTPsQ3XUx2z3OHtAMaYp9ru@5ohXwDPfwpIrrvnpqzpM8EAH00skHMAneTSXmQmFOdSupUrJ@PlSUIAmE4KHBASKMC8cTyTIPSPsw6hNZAkFlMYoWo9dsaYrkzJ39p0FhANvExjDO27QoIRqZBtLrUNU8kdGEy2qJshmmIpDaQvUIUHR1EcUw5TUWM6bYqUnnwKCpZ3x0uZo31uftx1gcWSlL2qT6F0utBd2tO9CEoDASlcmi5ZAg1hpUglgRoFpitfdJ1nWQQYzn1QOqFTMc5oZI10iSwhiboTS4EwRLP0URjj09T1plCVabUyolUUWIpuUIokbtKKOaQm3NgjQXkw@7YQKph3JZDaxCIUD4qBR6wSubGBR5pNnW4PRAAR6FuKKIBAQ8xaXMqhs9aeyiqGxQjCrWm44PW4ovEQs0Nan7f7UFlO7Ug78CwIOgMt0GJgCSInSaiIXKU5FiBhsc2sYgxGhFwh04Jquc9uQQyq/uRRV6Cpz0AncMYe96UTEZQEtYQoALD7fWg9r40RwNAQYZdYkwNaJ5QyLT2@ANHH3Fdl7IZY7SY2Zlt3QQYB3WZ3Se/SPomEB/k3B5qkljxZ9kYjWhGKEF0h8nAjg70wowYoyklDpeYhei5rojuXdf0aZVxveOYAWBkvtmnDQRaW2/GkoYo00Nddagu0gX@EzYyxI8Rckszg1GFdeEd04EGZEDdhKYPhYglu0N6oKTPCbeonuiGYY6CsLa4lKlZzpya8PgeqgnUVQiRif6AW98mm1fqDoDG9WdOykW1CZM@CrUXHTluOBIgUPEj1lQZf7Gn16IHiJMrsfPPEWYhBc/5FWkY0YaBOhNlFeMAGQrySMsYIEcMkOdQSRzanDe@nn1wm4/eGxKhF8eNqVGA@XCiFDthOlbjEOC2ryMSRzbiqi84IOiCw2tQ6/5wCWY3TqTdnXcVJV0E1vg6pEPXcZdgBWLGeBFk0YeWBa2Mh8g7dDuujLS5@AtlhGx7NjiF3Rn0pKOR60HLYKxnSgcgaJHN1a5Qb0/FPUZaJHcWO1joOJLY7QfYF0KAka1DXcAmhi0VdC4d@AWwMqZXA@dzWYxzCaatnuIK03dKOwBWmaBHdRwT1TbdmzIkkD3opCGiKbE8D5jhCXYVrCeKuhSR1lPoGfRuF/krkoO2@6uRi1ijd8cda3JVeTfQUfzI5050j/RQb/dA9IBGlEr2/GS6St1pyDkvXnJHgUSDsicPgBRIhCJP9XwRu4p7wGgOp46R4heaGJ8l/Djolfg0GDAgk9TIu6AwXE0dKhFYaYbH0K6prUr60IkLAjwFdKMpQQ9JRA/dA2kDGiHomuVyt6OTc@AeHhEmu0whiRQTRczFcZlON44rJASmZT6/IovC9wxqEOb6NswBgtOc005igYBvSAkakAcHSQp7WHSgMh/zo9INcxw7dLCPpJhAkiZnsQgMHUCKJsYCEcQyrKAdCi23b0fiy1qtBpUNZCpgm930vF4bDYSKwKkBWKQySRiJGLiHAbaNVBryi8AXLDUgPEFNrdXJWTDwoMVR@wUHQEBWzsGaHBE2LOdH1vG4e7WgHXREIB5bHYhOlhHwVQ5EANYaajdRNblAVdB9k0hVrLwYnqK@VnmpKxYoH4J5po9CcC1MylwJpzAFYV1dSiIWNHSbVejdqWGHIgEzQWNn3KgDyT8Ox79iRpQNZYKo0V5rqQwJNgeGhzzZObpfC9si85Q6llNZcLBdQ7ep8zqC81HYB/t3DnYOfrG9BIdtdSpXHSQrVypgVzueCH1nLOVEtbI@j2OG@G77ZtwYcBGG50JvIriTOVFpakDnMonI@fjgC1dJApIQkoPGAGa8r4g0DAaELq6j@4MrnTDpZzIQZRwkgiXCPolwxgZMOvrrUXqejF@@xMK7mqhR6I4ps8c6QxA5SvtOFE5EzysCWOTV6bEekYYFWdRycHJjZpqHjNLzDsrOVxNDBeq5KvPO43t7BzWKNhxdEyiI5AcgS@leV4Q6b49BEV8GA@wPTAbJiLOEo1RN07qUwIaxQOBZ2ZIV@AEBajyiSwR7GGXNH0Dad6/mjboKRlwDqJ1iuCpXzstDxudN6Fw6sIszUPFd1otSj1lnFTst7bFi38Vuy8jnzWKuPN9tGbM4u/NI6VwC9AOR3OiB17EvoIs4kyJDsTpM/uGDawn3qRAJqoAQpcy3iUjj8m0OtRfBIklf2gU9zbVN8X3K8XjCpyUpGU0niIZPVdA5@L2JFaTkNHsraYCF2Hd29tW7EXA4mE3HM6jSgBo59kxeD@cHDR/qiOPabt8lGxCGSYdRhCA2rczmTt91rpWQjo6Y1QROMQL/xeEbfQR9jfWSqo801LzSyiYrdcc/BS6tFDQkEqUQRSVRePEj/UQHcs3yfbj/4R50IkpelmOzTC8gwVwYSi40GXOu1IEIEJEYpmdpBuM5yWutPfIQ5iYFMdMho4sD7sy8lzpSjilKS@GXJuld9xrFP3KnV6oWuLCqBYY5ku0/evJg/9Hew50PmoGazy/Yc3K5AISD@DogC4kDRjdsrRusaWK2EF0C2oaHzQu4wBgUlGiSaex7wLhFBBFZAlbUGjabm3rXHThJP301M6foK3zkGKwKPcTGx0DDgKBod21URjw22439OdafQRCM/IokQSsfjDsiKK3SR4Zr632JhoOOwbYlBVWX/cc4uuEvCwGJ8acmC8GGuEB0mNJxRN0euqC80DlzZA0kxdDTsSvb6g9AF8aJddNLi3ENprmRuqAhgK4sxXmjDJjagLbhOyonnlXttxW1xOq1Iqs5iY/AFpo/wK71TFCdUtBbASnSV6ykebt5m0yBSyOmq0gSRNyggxw@wb7AJiBI0rFT1PMj4lBugaOmyCsojV6McUwXuJSUl3NFpZCXQC0DNQ1kVgFH3oShHhgDIXAFwCe4PTpuMFcLe76hOz1xIzREiQW57xZkVWs8azadFgjozds0bThd3Zi2GkorXSXXg2yE8Okq1N6F7GHdjRyg7lIjVE36Jiv4WVe/zs66Om1dXSIFw1HY5wgj8nAHBKmXLvDrrjnf9jCANO8pbSzASgj8SloyIGRjUA4fSCkJGhT0tFD1JEyXAEIviodQc4BvzQUgs9GMWGCaBgPgHxpJ7VJT@rqEi85ayDUWk4JDw@JoCiyPAiHTFjRMUORBIxwxDJiUJKhAKPGgf5IlgQ4kHHnA0kdQTGxAaxc6AlDnfByKDLALxjmbMRsbxiYZWnHAc0f4kOjCy5uEiwgaEF/@8LNeiCcW20RyR8caB1S4ItmFAUXyFFkA9OVTEtCRhq6JajyumXjqWKiIiBz1FaDrSq63xcBbIzzEdfnDP7385LuXX//k8pNvXX7y65ef/vHlp/9@TXiFOmZ9M9NsCmK20SJ88lrib@2pt3bu3LpToikEeRIS/3//0q//3W/8ymLal8T744@/9uOPf/lvf@WTv/ns4x9//KWf/OjrP/nRV37yo6@@UbzO//WrrvHfPnHDKE9xaGQ@wjA@iG4wgF70PkhtjY1bp2dkbW0Ngq@tbUFJrG1tkQzZgqcAzzXoN7fANwvPLdIA3zXSIhctDjRYnywZ7RPp@Llo6sagDdzSMFNaWoQu7@x8ck4Gg8ZEhHZ@zBsbfOuCzi7RvgBnXFiid7HQDumyGUz7u9B9M9ss8auibkjNhtxsNc9SzW4m3byQskoLtOy2hQ8/paYbiigK4Ia8JSWJZ6ULKU7bhEICkGgMvFnK6IQdW8WDujSr8PesCfREwCqhIs2PyVPWQid3cGj1Q3M0mHrzAPF4FcinOPY8WxyCa2iQ/83zl5cs/LwotKAjRxIjgwOxEIe9UNIYTRlf5FhKm9LC2qSoxzoRekM30KX3RFA3xLmOJrmWlAQB@hDqwzDRbD@0fANUC90x3bE/P0a3dOgQYwfXo8EY2PfuwBpxpjFwoaZvA04Sz5IgkXHCR2DTRlGwriHCjc0aWQZOMUBvTNftWFD4tPXSUQyFRn2i21Y3HsvOF0YvxDi2Kg1DZIzI6juuZwpACAjB0UVKdA0cV49mc/fpSNE1Xhn60i4A@a5lBllyz3Z1SlHXgbowVxtxLmQWHvRZCHJgdjnbIUIPRAuRlYBndqUNjs5tut4A2CXkBqds1LiMhqGH5PqjrhhMICiXwg5q3pNpQyCknZKuqqoFI9@rRH5YF4DYAyga1OIcUAkjL0EBz3RYtHtsGCXSaR89vrvHxhpo54TdEY47tYdudwxyWKhnHJhOP0v2oBZZjjsEVupE4V8e2weuGzCtGCyrRjKYkmkNx7ZOx0iuDmPcGM5wO65Nh05uCjqDH3u@buts0Cby3XnvIcjGT48Oa2JlDkjST4Y3xo3jdsujZfTcn5@po7OU0XSKzyomv57nsZuLVlkicwk9SugxxHWUICuGWjS1xo4h4JkiXyDsSnUjhlMoHJORZhGdKSp1Pwl6vQVnjTofC8hL7JlzjjqztZUL6pDXmQHlGRAutFyAmUdUoDDxesuVcEUKx5ZzQGWdeZSoh05XXwo4dL/gW6a@s@WXKP2EHCyesB@YdjQBd2AOXZxkgl7SxtkMEO1RkGULJE3oK0Y4l0DZNM5QQZegQ8CrghY0sZHAoLnEGm02HcuRcKKIW5dIOEJcpQ0HtG42s@czFuqCZkwHHzbrbEYYNQ@PKT0SG7tebwOKzXo1WrC2CgxjSiZjMIqVpg1C0GzSSfBrWY2XNPh0SJqjQaqcL4HQPVFloTkp7rXOk5JPydAjfLM5uSWrH4BMgksR129LfbNK1wOtoFc18klShh325RyFYsO7xgC4C8lMFkkJ5TN2eq7dFdhcEtQ1wrQQLKBwQj9eIhmuhDUtL1odSZensqDIVecWVl7De6VI69cB5pZixohQfCDnx9mTc9I4zpIT0R/ZVgAiEsoTg3BVkXN10Sadz9I9T5/6XLgepEZ2Dt55ryG3GAZuqOP8UImV4iRa@wtam@eOcbU2mHBVS2AFtNens/YW5heEHAhApxIg@YCDRVAlcURhjqjkY57P8tIzQZ9LmVRcmg6zxExfiD1bDwLTYXWOTdKtJjebTQmjqdHot8Kh@QqR6fyF1YNUgh8ksUoOj@7uHRyIKNClkns4z1GB5giiIwgjqzIdUXI@8xVyq5sktzBMGpVbDpoaqOvtMDxU6ipU@rGJsznIdvqmlwLHNE5RGOBMZ4VoQCaNhQTCtUlGQGkUI0uBsr3FkFWWpv@pc@y4p3GJV6DGZyglgdyp2xWUMtPi2LFeiD50L1TQBJBQn4JeoraeopxsXUmHi8@GOMEKQjUVECEHjQYBnYlfB2CetFpVNlMOsOAHbkhdnqdFQZeI15So6GvgDIIMxRAGr70izxqyUG5l1pehoguxwtXdLP9zeBHDImrfXBrteoq292sNmaWBzZgx7v3Up8sfF/c4VMg6M/BsZJaCR4uLKNOha5EW1xQtrliCRoashA5YYEYilpAI196HdZb6U84PWi8Gow6pNDmLia4iycn5OaUhWVcJpSGYFMIK4yLSioExPXAhNw/CdffzMgFtreFyC2yzTY6vxNq8KIsyj05MTpdOrgijwgn1jTRzJgxazrFLp0NiU1sWlTwKgHHo4bF9PSSu1KSPBVA6mTqDVZf4MOFt2OnRxxIAOisQzjdTBzreHIq@IDPq0gF90aHnJTEvrrFYiDZcw0m7WDAT4cVrIIVyiQL3Oh1rFSgQARdPRe8lYMCdsCKrYk5UZlm8ugyHLNA3XFQavv/7x12g8/VSGEBPgANwsaENfTOWiNBbWShhULTQx/ICZOPEY9vSKQGo6XUoDd2DLOl2bFiOms5FCwL070McWQ9LFuogPkCivKE6sZSzibHovTySZXNLDvBEYxXslWVJLCo6CwL6WpcSgUk5lkkDUd7ECsGcsJmIOX0Z@dTrExWtHSK00rJyH4yDMXuCUPvaQrRGeN/UBkNIOa93FFNiy7hvKHJPPx53XWF03I8F0cIS2Fnu6TCRAP19OCvaRuPy7LMMsmXR0XsV2Kzvkk7p63W1wnfG/kjoUOW6y2y0IQxviMGz2XMViBXugYsNq6lm2fTxhjUxxA4VJVwUIOHCS2GOaNYVMtt6Z4pCxuDz17J4gh04Ts3IZGRtxQzraLQ6PCqUNHy5vDz0RDQYPZap/hJb3BlqVjTD4XLP15QqdEvWULcFtTtnXMm0l83PXwONp/ZoGNyJQLcj3FjJseMxxrbuzUw3VPFro8nXxqXDbuGJZbjQz4@IUhQVdcYco7VgM5S4ipY@5ub7rWUEi3ZRCLFpeWN3jQDXSK6oPW/AutjaRFwBOlcdRHcVTQz3FO@VAsEAtEz2XN53vVyaqjdgQ4Jt2Dr0zCsZ/8LoHo4evqZKnlq@SR/LCXu8NKGBYS91X6zs0bjd/Djc6yqwb9muTw7p8yYC9T2gAnsur7rztLR0R6Bj2PPmG7hNNKk/K1Dd7rt2odSXdHisLPWx10MOH77flJfFvEhRXsOLIkHHdZTwvZKDH0ve8esKiO7d83BB55zxhs50GUMKJy1W5w5kfNywsDxn9@QSDSlKbGxvRcS4jOVUn0bvn6OTWEXaqJMYTamADHIcBiiXwBB4TGj@eWLL3Rxb982Y0jW0xddlYq5wj20TuiX6vFakRJWVzxlCkeU3Z1E9e2yOzaWqw@POR2bYYbx55HKY3PVwSB1H8XHnRQz1MtTp3ih12POi7UamoeOs3euFk0XmNQJ5eoTa7hMwPEHD9RB9ZzxaKL0Fvco5YKQZjKIm6nYXUoE@n5evlF4j4yxI1r5J7xt1Haab4QqnWl6W5VD0mJsCWbDcpANpcdiPLPZciJi6zGKeweK0lzdnXB4HJcv8GrqVLEVdpXpT4HJZcizHDKb4fEPu2HFd@/OUFDBJ3Pfqgp4p0LWiN5XYNfEl3AVBZoMLPg5JdHqrhhVY7xFqhUAfVHdvKvT5OZo3Kk0BZyGHOEO0aF0eB44Y2vqw09VJqnPqpq8jxS2ZOEjDFovaq0XBcHhCEUticVY6Xbdj2jp7TQq5m8KVRW1J2w4nP3GylE2Rzia0E1d4x2gKebW6oB4MzKFJrTeI13oXT3YIXyuBJi7eq7wnpmlIkz3TWAUwsqBZO/hcmJOdk10C1wHFJsB1Zqgg2LiSMXRdTayHume5D3YevTM/uR4C7A/1vnkv0g7mhgRwoQxTnGbG5YMDFXIHm5IBwUK0oWDpHJtTP3ovDfhwakBBjYcrG52Bo4Nv0MpWrX283oU5A3fgDMwBW3Ac21bVUqhIAUUc1h6nP8C1TqPRwhroeTrYrm3P0wFZDGM4rttbGsce7oXELTxLw7MN1uHrtcNUesAaHxpWVtOBOQY@7ruBOzIFalsFauOQBnuu4jnRVO3PO1Zyo0YLpIjePy/@1@pWfd0NRiP6ao/ssU8fNKhAt6q@Tp7osbUVdBWc6/XFl@6wI4aOYrjwgs7mLm/THSswBrhXmNVIs@92jIH1ukSH5xNI0eAGs76R7oaUsYhwF51BoQfyelMR60tt3v8QX/urCj0cJ2GdQWy4oX9fNhZFd@MKI/3Y8Nm4H5pIBYc@51oX27NbobueKy/GVjBDOrcYJx7IZAPtaFiV9nANwUpJhC6Kn7HDcG3BylpKhVcUVAVTBgFBWRXt4vKsuSamaeyxlDcYrnHci9jzSkqG61LoEJc1N/gI7gtVZ2FBzVLJ2hmM@/513sbGnLsgreBjtUZO16XOjbtCt6A74WsVBVVbwg1r8G6D@DE2b5wYyN84M0DhFFvQXQtebXhBqYxXDg/Z1shnTyL0Vs4bhetsQM28OrnFaDNdrieGBdM1e2wcH02vk8lAvwbhtQ/9uWDgfC8OAyOfZp0240mO2wd@LdhkBhzBrtKVlq6DWV78cfcmfPDI7Ou4KPaBFeDywSW1graPZetnXov7i2Pdt744hpytqmy4B5/NmXnzqyfRtgTfQ71vGfcXCiJOZEjgcO0hey1Uf3S6XhanA8vHdTex4YYxF6xyrBJjrWuDCL0E8urgc3z8wKwBsS1tS6GXDRC7oynu/JlS001jw1ZABxDD9yotatUqpxsTcToejsZ@@FqeBrqyZ36AdcjYmX9qAXLhBXBNMtDtYPkg7NxoIghSYX83My6PskI@tGy3Tz4syQTkroBYKOcuqTh3oOd9gstGPGdJTaRxv@HcHer8ApPb/BdQtiYuUHes4OYBjCDAJSTRGzPDOgX3FOSBB/gUtz8vBuFoOUUezHVy8XbS13TRUMMO3bFnmGiMz4iYl8hD7OZutALWwl31eMbF6bxmY7g2NCMw2EubhuE640Dwxs6N3L9wI/ev4DlBc8VNUl/ce/g0PV/qdJ3w6wTJ6CSpmWnl7PaVymQ5IEut5peL0JHYf5edcHNAl6u@JswOHsNjULZ8112mgjyZQkexjJmPh3dNA@eyXhvHI/eh67jQu4yA8Q0PTLYfe2GVwfKAGOwB7jgGOnRfG80hRbuiU2HSgz4yO1CO9sz0Jn0LQ3xXD/QVXQsd9qIqWWx6bZ2w7I7pfUTHs@bMq7TGxQTdNydUDVhdMVhbEwLDYNIrDjUttIWFyQV/5LoOe1LuKcNLeXgzlwDWTh9vPnsr4qLvBdV7qSq1mNXHJ2zpgtllBwasyqtndlybPW9YEONYbKJa9yzTlx7g/nPqVsgRAaQp/0ZeUbyRV8y0GJBMT3Sfzhwv1wpmKJXJ51iXMtA9w8VJm9Bww5KRuU3jr2HH8TpyNpvdAcJPgDPpxjg84vF1ybKHnSF9rFQA5krzwIRourhg7XDqBPrkemGywZdwm/ncMqN4c3bElrBRF0jqCWgX6eUK3BXqWSP6oJx35QwuXSkiOJZpvNRxoMmldJkNry74Q96kR9S4Yrh1rrnQgVBJp7uNl7aYxXVTIIjYphAMPFDDpeCmEdroqIslQ/rjoYnznosTCStFTtcf0My6y6d4YybqmUJ46hrwjPgENibXCTsrJUZED//Hd96VoFNtF3LR8Q/Aol4/qQyJH3tO@HqTmvbE9YOeNXkM6cY15qvYBmYrD0HgxVoAmjZWZQJKzxnbbECgP7foZ9ilapRAD9AVBJuy5cAUTOdEoIdxTa7nyGXbh6QdPFs1MLtCuBcdB8uFB9FOohgsfC@Z05vngbiiUJEYYSeFXLjGcBlxTyMOAPKTGwgjn76lkf9k/8HjI3HkK0v7oZ0Brr2/JpctbG5XS/LcKNFHujc3NcfWQnUtP5DuHCrC7oN9EQFW0JuN3gvwwsmlhdfKocjoPE1JX6m9oK8ZLBf47h89fJCZbbwjqd2B5w7N9Lz37uFhFvcxvHu41Hs@9D1oHT13sjL4/p6ipJdU33B35iouuSSmVZiOTNAioTLeZ2djvFaIMtyR2T2ajsz3oJNETu2/YfSFlZl8pJ9YfWyFpLySULShkrJYyKXnlv@Ckmx68XtVeR5bI@SWBn1J7LVyhQRKCJrkaculhJsmp69KK0QOJ8c/XyBFvl5b5090lXT/n5owRVFW0flQ70G5kvzKwloEWDbFabsnbzAbaobKiBA7CQHUKsF67WLlojAE1i3hA0fMQ0cwdlauzLgJQexcWNrgT01nqjsCSkuhy8iNpYwPzbm5mnixyAke97x02ipeb01SBjVGZD7y5rx2d@/sRx4HzD20vfPoKXmi@6DxLMFozmGcSRYfCTheg6d4rRq42O96wKlZP9EfLa/3FXKoe13XmU7mmgrO4mJXRw@ujMOgjQKZtjWxlvFug43PPFm@EiSKg62Qd6cLct78wRhhgMsv/7qiyDI99gTfisysVyowSaFJn@KZWfNeR/tx1TewXxbBIb1Uq3pgTnDFABulXKacLuXfhRt4ezG9ml3e5Fe6wS93Q3zX/NAR91QoNyDM3@BH8mLs/cC1TweuuKt75g3kuCnp5RuSXp7jN@FJzHT2KjSvFlpxJXj4WlrfjszAy40GbsfKLYjIixsoVw63B7pH1x/03XDxPLMvj@p0HDXkh/pLc74JH8/4gDkY45LxJRNpHRDETKdvsYPXyB032KO2G7SFeH/o8rlma3R3PLrCSvCM@ivc6X1QytxTn9zBHT8z@XCJcolri5a7rxKmSDzChGcM3j/aiSJ9fCipczHOUvHBkwVn3BMXPD6cc/PMyWSVtiVMVikvS31msT46yi1Eu1l/dvKafRXQswGri98ru1zGd949vN46UVMYBEM78nlXd8wIT9cN6CapeBxuMpoNjr4/oBUg4mNLFnRBL2JZgMOX2m08tKTdXlVLjswP6MAy9JUkMCco1jMBPzwbyJzkBkH4zQ4aZGUDcI9jrn04GljOJLQMZ@641o2kPvKjHO@QQ9s9JZHCM9d8wh4LgugnpnPzpiahrN3cIWvzve4Cndjh/@FrFYnurOi975ietwzmwJDuRZb31PQSiHcPI4Blvru2i4OkXWs8XOZNg2Yyy7y8hYZ9NZC1zAPPrj8euJ6zzDMqmErljrkS9doNfsMpaGvLPDq93jLnPd9d5vxwbAcWCmmR5yN3DK0nqlZ7XiS91TfrzaZYEWdWPIrXH3jpeRfgFEN37IN4Z9npq6DCR1aw4HiF3tQNzwI2HdFxr@J91yVfsGbpnM/Ey5VUevfezGdxnHiMM4V0d9zMuGqn1Giqvbb6vrT61LK84jnW8Irv7Jilfc91mC09P@8THbK0BNt93bbSqydC1dfMhCKbY/7kRFvWyoDh35un6HvTSSw5P7Hplt3QtqtCBvqGkQ4/FeHT1ZeKNjcowJaMrFj2NmPZX9wb6sb8kOPCWQvRtJE/Y@JzmoV3@OjOztH7Tx6E9i/ow04UQ3Q8unqXrdqK12hcGUahB8hLh/gU/IEOfRcdQRFw9/SVGbT3dx48idjxAERyICWe8TY30BTzXZLqer4@LMcS5MNon9JdaHtonnGi@1PTFcZxplh/t0zNX7l74OoZUTdDz53sdK00HpnB4djrpVduZFWXKzuHD1ax1XejbB6@8/DdL96bbXN6ZA2JLKrwv9IyREWUrzqp152060656075604FUb4i862QBsXlWmmMqHwdt3It7er1hKrXE6peT6gaJ3TOKdzNzXaFQ98/f@6@nw3Pf2KnKLC9674YfRwhlXKA5aYXv1E1vxEfT6dOrePprOt00z3Anp@TtXCjO3jw0db5cGs/HuJoOWMT9@azr9QEtXWIplZT8mWyhR@AqhBFpnHiJ/PK7Ky8KLIGWT8Lt61XKsoFWasRvsKT8OCA@OhrdnwzIMaDZyFTRDhWyHoAPuvRpndCv0dCzgkdTRUMPN8TbKI0f/xHNTwWANK0fvZk/8ne4dHO0dPDhty6CI8NiHLhOBBbdDjJLa3LQ@ZDuoEWyw5zp8dV2BAd/QgFjsL6Ub4Ifn9pMWu1hazNMsVvYZj1M8eRJHpygiRcQPoEnsVGfVGMBCeGO8oxLaDw0IwKO8SAnsUAZcRQ8zROKLQKkZdFPNJ9H7IV@l/9hBn1xe/fVfALeBhxeP42SK191@2GMfomef0VxXhvZ//B04M9EiVwVmtOrW4wqJXz7Hj28GQ2Hs9RsOkRI8kwSBLKqlZL3ksCYZJiklToWRf0aHQ8xS0Z1wc8JSMMvUFS6xQ/UDAZF4r03z@WLpIibr1IA2wySlQSooU6TysKnmN3BJWE3D3Yf2/vgGD69@5SZyQRoiBHuA//L3/QZR8XiY6/ir795w1DLQ1Ky3etbgVPvzBMksgpaniETpfg0W/sgAhiTuiHOmjNo0NEc18DTNMjibj5IzuicyxmR21gyVEOMB@SfQSEHmERf30k/ogSx9Ej9qC@n9ITIq8cnpimB5SxLx2yY01j1LTqRR8ywClU0CqpZGH5Fh6ggeXQc8felUaCm9rpWaEi2cHPIuLHF3X6nRxI7NgJ2Flr4flLCaihYsyrsmSdJpZ9VYefA0xurkEj6Zig3BPfsUCQDCrkI6jBOH1ZYQesCEI9eS1IhLpCTQKqjnOATM0d4mn1RBjt4aF5TU@6/LVfkfpVAuYAzF8NzRP5Dti@Ftp6YP46Mz@TsIJKyWsfU4nTMp8gPEw1zAFLCNezfvYz/FIqn1pXlOO2d5JJ5uUqPJRqnuTJrfWmIKw35Nr2ug6EDF5MmtCcpY3ciXl30Ovu96Umz4O0mZOkjbOzs@S9jSfWszwpCF1LLbyYTC@0gvZicqEppRfHI6XQEF9MWnyplj1uNRst8uTJB6/ar9L85IQOMqaggu0@5pUcn6iUydlWQUscl/FDapDDY/ISruMewT81v@zOmXU0d3pQb5M8STSb@FlTvsgD20u24E85xXO4GM9o1MW6uNV69Srd0PVgMiWWZY38bhdud0BSqpo@JNDUbkMjYgEk0qRvSkS48sNJj0x2zH5/vKdPrfG9YFssiiVRnWNMmw8/fD@8qu8/fUrIU/L06cuDFWyslcmkBKFBzZPI8QEIgNkJqbT1fAI/hfaXn61dZM@etDf/8pOhZK7h6zG@vnrxEM2HSv7W2tqtO3dyuayqqsz85MMnv7izs5O7m80/aeS3coK8tvkXf762pqqbqrTW8n2llWwcH3/Aq3KOF//y@8n2kydf9P269t8@flVX8FGExwkpkjJeGlHAiM8S3ArJ58mbXomXCQWuxJT@2onI/WyNKPWt4v/45uMXiSBRV6X3PXgHiReJQinBjGAAmxbZThL1xCaCFS4SU6lWq4Gx@D/@A4Svvwt40Ge6CY96PsJVmCbqQo0GOU/UC2BQVBXi/X8@/nguhcDPgJXUoEUKpchtGxhio8Hniiq/1YJrg16bHJ47JMiSFME5wSAwXaKUbiu30WKBBV4OvHCUqJnAj0E@3ibis4MM9AkZ8b36mnR3U4BLHEmKojYV5TawX@HWRq0mQL9Cm62m5W/jmZBp2hv23cAl5u33F67E@/9TrqVoqu//z7wOyK5lmJ6b5RKFte3nd@t1yK9W1zbqGXqFjYy2t2KJd91t4DVHg7FnufhVyeoD/D5KnZdLKp/NZrcP2hCETCZIQmEyEduIgrAPVifYJbYJc8HmHDqyughXHTlBi8TuLFRkncGR58kGtJHW89VwiT28/uo//dW3/@qb9Pdtev8XPLTJ6Vo9aQOATqC51OHarlSMep2ve/xZE@11qGNypVQpSe2LZmqjUW8dgFj7znkyryXJoT3NQiZUlTTTzQYNX6fR1sPo0V5PzJzrzKU@7xZ6MGDqAO@QUiQR5XMuXzHVCLkCxyWihUZC46TeEnCssiY0lEK@JbBQjW0oHF4tlvl2KyGsT4ETqa26mlcfk@06u8hg3ScupkZTC1FGwvTWZ3mb@cxs9XmnRD0KVp/BfF64ME1lLtFoSC2T9hX1KKHba5W1UqVQUaV2ffVVnYXAi4KapvnET5wk4qtKwnoY0TMR18w5t2fzJREXC4kqMFkI@xo4KCtgGpNJ@FfVpWyZFpdWUPhqaFLbPKlC/VA1Qe23eVmB1rbdjoX3LbjW4Ef/cMVWfK5Rl9CZgly/1khF2VA1KX@rsKdi13v18oRGPUM5o9CqZ0TkkIJ4BYaDvoQYnU7npdEByUTXO7qhK4E@1if6VA86486kExhjAz8WTJ6geNcOyeBpbt4tuRFVRCGh5ZX1xG3Mm6aW8bu7oJuUSlpZ1YqKVixoRVkt5bVSWSvmtGIREGpFVSuXc6qqFYpaoaQVClqhjN82BpgCwGiIoZjXyhqXeNVYIweMv01IJrqamddeT0XK0fCiBhdvQXAnCRCcxsZxlkv8M1x1RVXIBnSOMjxAIqRGotIf5HBXt8Z@liMJEPbOWq82Gq82yHxpCWGa4SW2t1sZ4eKiAeZqNfxv1mNjlV7MBFltXWQym8/qIAM9qzcygPJZiFIUCEUqtuuktUm94tjC6EL/zRZp9cE7M/L7WGcEmooXkIrMZmOz5u7SW6TNU2hBNJsLSd/epnVtG0LV14ENpDOZdUFYawDuRthDATDWyDCPgKlFUiDAnJ39nDfZ3AQmc7F5Ub9obF5cbG7Cf5M@L8I3uF5sXvsnc26y4G5T2@xaCjoHcNFCPtVsSPWm1Ax5VQvsolRHF1FqgqEOb4BraGqphb0jSj9i61/mX8zOnrELJrklQqq5xAbZSOA5R1pig0s8v/z0f8O7efnpD1GSJfAzK1zijBAuIW2UCXWjrzKIcw8d8pBdDpjxjqzogg71h@josIeD@rEkPRdJRaBKckopFdIidv9tt9fGjaQieQ6gALbXN6ERRbyX8GqpwLczylQliU2@UKTs9heuXclk8l89V8vFJNPBcSfkc9/3H86lcpZOAK6qsiIo53V2bi07WPwXll3/6hdWXVzivEyQRinC6MIloBolJAl0Ry5R3xzisjz8KIeAX1c7qX0gPN0Rdt3hSA@oko4jeCAq1Pb3auVyHZUnc/0JbTsbdzfgqcB/bw0yQZo9AG32asYQBPNmT8urTdRV39FBZwdGJ3Re4O/BS/yRIwN/By/wR45e4u8gwB952MHf0Qv87XTwdzTE350X@Hv4En9P@/hrvqVpSpVf10@6ky78Jy/XJ@tnlFYZpaxcrE94RrPEVr35FpDTT1bJdvKtBh0LypdbDfRtgcdbgTethJ@b8Kd@FldNmgZS3DRSvLql8ukqKzJCUlqunH6LDcRUyFtEr5WrnZpaDYPHQWuOG9tEy48@@pdi22wrahqHP7Ry3vUEnVg@PMAho5UV10v@9BuffJKs1ZJCkh7QngM3oYNAHQoEVgiZq1o15S1QYV4JZoWlLmWm36KDbpW3CME8vYVjlq6XGqYtJ9llm0ek8djqSpYr4edtrf5Ix5V@Eks@nr@me8xNOjGdE8l0xkPppTXSRyPJNw3PDPBQNqgTk@AEoGbhRKxJXT3QpZeuY@LglhS4QxsxJtkZwyle4tOVdpsFabchVVUrg3kIx7VYLlLWZh5ymbJNJ@WZIy8lKul0XaNHlwpCTstB7vNpPH64no8clTLYlfRbUHhENNmXqxJQKRUuUSPryroi27IhKx2lAwaLyB6RB/JA6YL621aIbBJ5Kk@JPHSVLphM@MlgsuQekftEdmQHAMEXTEFbDtDUg1cffj1A5MHPwrVSHUU2CERko5JMvxmF6MF03ibvDFw/yI6aXIMkCf/cfP78OU5jiAWrhV8QaPDPnzeljZZaLhERGYPYbjxvJlt8k8fzZdVyjnSm5lrzOQ/incyz8kYXAvlsJFvVhNRsSmEtVXO04l9ctNt7j@622xLKGU1i1jPbGegjt7dr0GeGr61EvbrVrNBuOOqKE9LmVrOuCWguZKBDVcGN3DehSLJS5nNeM8Twrq9RArSenz4HbTJ1ijrl6Qm8TiPD@014tJm2Sb2l0/ebc1ZqgAthJen9JRgWDJBqx5vGkiP8QSX/5/pb/7L@D5@SdKrRSqfOLjZT9EqnSJqk0un02cXZRfisp1Op0JLahB86gB0DnV3U0UiBzsDUSKVb6YsL5gbPVBrA8QdBNus06AzsjCRYlOEvfFALAQNJzVxYqlKpeZgZCOQCIFgwnKVahIod0qnwagKff85vbnrGebNKmX1OLpME/7yqz6Ztms2JLKeBdYcHYAsOWdfP6Rh3umrg1@XWOw2l9Rffp4ecb6UpUD5XrSobhFnUnFqt5iJbsVStliLLeipVvn7V5S2lAIpoLpdOV6tg2YrQymCFsA3yKkNqpAnP1u3bLJKSen4e4dRyhYyM02XVahRTHqI1fd2gDR7007P9x/SAcOAY@QRBxhAO@Kdk@oGBE91OJfkKf/t2KvyE7NZO@vZttSyfn8cuoxE4KQtO7XbX8tptdNfOz/k2T2daynmwy6Xzc0UuZ5QkAbaceoTfAUUGLijkllqn0SJ7VnNF8E42J0pBwc5Np51boQReOa0MeWLdcTXJJ6t84oxmQikVGSfjqXMCWjRwdf/sIkGLkeTy6RQwwTSI4hcJ/HnIL2kvouXz6WpOlhNnFzwDVsplBp0muUKqlCmHv9paug5iJvuhrKxlchvFjW1QRfDnT5ZdyFGrZ2ZNuaidmRX8tMxF1Qg/sYi7ls3bt7Uy0KUkJ8jdMZ6dkG1yITuugciBEis8mlwymSG3bnO4pdtLVqrbtFSVUp4kklXmKCSBrZMSEFhSN/JKCSnCWT08iwDELk6hSv0aWeNU@sYHV2aq/ho6JrhEzPxu/HNduEiXdEgfL9JHzZ5YxKYXsQnzp0/DiIFcdoW@sZWGxSt2MeOLTWhoeY1V2yR5MDYsHFR88mBnd@8oq24KJKHe29nNqodP7yQUtOZnduqtof1gb@fu46cQ4MmDvZ3DvXf239t7@gTcfXI6u@KuI@pA4o5kzrTEfkre5z7yXuqmqZtj02yfjsenL8hHltW2oLztMeTN7XvEN9uQpZE@y14VbsPy9Y8@0r0Rvcjl9758@b1fuvz9b1z@/pcvf//bP/3021@G@wdwf4O9v/HH5Tw@f/rpr//h5e/9Pjj@F7j/DO7Pfvrpb3/Mbmr/Edz/dc7tR@E9B8duDnB97aeffvP7P/3069@B@3fD@zvX71/7bPn97S@tvjHcN//wZphv/Ae4/4jhimC/8XvMDd/X4H@PwX39O5e/@R/Z/y/CHxp///I3f4SP0PKr3/mL/3r5yX9W1dJf/LvLL33z8kufXH7pq5df@tfq5W//O0Wef/zh5bf/5G/@9I/@5k//Df3/gD7/6E3@l9/51b/@3//6//jrPw3vz@D@j2D67K//M7Thv/@T7@H/m3/y93/2Pfz/r3/w93/yrb//2r@lht9hhn/83T9mzx9/8uUff@k3fvzJpyueX77x@ekbuH/6z@Dy5ul8Ezxvkq/P6/Lpz5Wefwo1ZrFAHYCa@8uXv/0VqLy/SRLk8ss/wP0TcK/4/0BVKMwPmO3/Bwb1ep7RRwYT3N@6/PI3yAdIpf8FqAR/8sEH0DV9EI5Gf/DBByEFv4p@4P4BdWTXYkDmGfnOfL5KZnBQDN8lpPH8eQsnixdQU8tPP/2N71NbwqzU6UQgdvkltZTZAO1oo1wOu/1wjhCCfCXGmljEkC9pjuNUw5i/itxrIZKvIt@7/N7Hl9//15ff@53L730NO30hV87uZAXlNROtAJh/AzgELLwJHAJC9O0MHSoVMmA2zyXc2LN9TkgV8qGVtOYM3JR6vY0K/Ag8KpWNs6yw1QRpjeb4gobFnUEg@CmCeiuztSYRRc9qG5oOgFKOwZGKsy3nMsUNXZe49rmEu4jIOZkzSgqDlNSQlswL12ZJIWZJUWOv9QhBnA0ukcHkZqgYtBEJZ3mNTDJhTibhZDy6A9Bkgxon@KSu6D3hJnTOPvrPjBOOZKhwRC/8YFRkpIYwXDTfX4Q7zEge4spM4nUAVGQkTFrbYC50KQONPAfaCZ0HzUxAJQcDzjOA1x3QBmq1DAassUSBlaWvXiI0PZlMDTKPoVmYbLuEKCZ3KBYIWaN0qE1YwAziq0c0yXDoRFOTKdXuQoS1yV10yCByivb581q9VJvUEd0rRpTMJHOHpgmR1TKT@iuw1yhOCMcl7r6CpJRqmUy9hBFiJlkZ4SwollSeZo7mHefRWUHAGxezbW0TcotXSjybrVpDgjFofGZm0AiIQQ6e84rKP@dzqswDcDOzEeaN/iMjvTco9ddovGGULO8Y8xpFRtrPN56HgBQSYhMEURQJ3LhwZItsky2OUS2ToYmBVyYkIq0stHLEDoRSisvQUmdkA/zgTD@rSVQ1VwWdpErQyTM4/AoXXY0kc@sTXGl2RkJZWQ4/LXnB6QCTkzXu7FwPV6Kt6@QCnAocQtA4axuf@8LEItXW19e5RJ3X@Md07j0jScQ7rtD1hND2qHZVIXyhzKOzSRdXMio@xO0CWY6aq5hNcvnx9xM5uZjg1pP0M76ERURuZdi9vb1BbgFZ6XvObUKX7QkZzc25CUbGzUyGVyHSugu2DUrCDMXGPSOJGv7BPUGrG/TCT3TP8rNcljK@LLzEWgK9yePHj8P0UodnNS4D7VDVFLTjvOt4PIbgZhfXOGSzopgVs9nwLdI3dRBDg0h9w7e4jqQn82qgUizh9zsdY4B04V69egV1g0NaVPZxOJkaSU3NlagnodVgggvq9GGWY8ca2PY0Wrer5socG8AgSiFHSIrWCLjSBBeopqCOpzm2yo1Vr@hKJdVSKUkhocTEFIAxNAUFORVbCUw3MJF8ccEKKZu34tAkm0LAxRfxElyWvlQpn448dx@T3ccPH@49Ohq1WtDZ0O/Fmu2R5xqm76fQb@fRXVZ91XIhnWg0MO9HFRU5J7dXkbEaZ/bvHuwfVgijWFh0KZqPKl23ENKlrHCJ0ej9zYSH0xieyeNXklz@EJ@VGSlSalmDoIk6lzBMVMugnuIf7io5MPtYfR/6/TvuhKTkLM9nlQJq0mmchofk/KI7JngKIjt6AbgDrpYUIb@Y8vqZMDeRhw51cqByzCAo1EC0cikyFJlBKRYQ4DH7jpjG1Q/3jgDz0WOiqLJIDtyOBYmqf0AmIiHAAw7coelmhQsaGjnSkTV0EcKu2abTDwbr@G1WvinzcwRab8hZ/KmaBk8lV8gq@WJrbc0@ExBPk1aZM1wLegHWMwFp8jZchHubI2@DE1zCBeHckemQcKZj/3GVVV7c1EtSkPrDwOOVPPCFNIdTPyE@bjR/VZHq0NAWJ1G5xNqHHwakXt97dFfYv4cDFpMBiVaSClZXHIi05nTHnkl9@4R0rfcs3HAgdi1/ZOtTaMVAsI06UCTAGe7ExcVFD3Du3yNqXaVWFraLzwuDunTAfDHROQIcusclbkdjNFzxdqVSe6XkipC2SuWVpqocOHAbEpewemtQ3eiqoA2J/XinllPkjMIG4FMOSfM8X/UhUZpWkja4hMLz8NI0jaMtiHAVkyN0rdgruVYTQiafU@hSMQ7PhtcnNTW@QtjJrRmsJjNY9AEP0g88Ikd@ReYX2qJ@AbKCi6fpV0KjcUH59m0NR6q0nBznnVDSkAso03Utp9FCumc6AdYzgr6tRK4YTktCPlsJzjYD0q2BOdHEjNN42WJ0/FK7T8YAWcgBSzytqAqbosqpuQRPEBoZpVaSuUQjATyAa7Qatf/vf60G15r8y/0DWRqNGjcBVjp/h84IQ99k4cdxD93Hs//jx8N5643/4WP34WN36MIfusyHyOmrs3@1umC9@R@yWOSy1SqkGOcOoabKILDkwfqP3/74H37zP/3Db31VxCu0xQ7/@O1vMfff/XV8fuvb//CtX/qHb/0Wdfm1f/jdfxN6/ePv/gG5C7xg@lLHKnr59U8uP/3jyx9@dvnJdy9/@Kdonf9/@u9Dr0@@NXMEM7pc@X@L/O2v/Z9/992v/s1nH//dtz77u9/5kx9//HW1pPz441/5u9/57G/@7GsE7D/50Vd@/PHX/vZXPvnxx78McPP/n/zoq5HXl2JHMIPL9T@4A17uX8yFHBEXVtC1Apvh6ZR1uti/oZRzrT1gKg3S2owOrqwD9CbbmEfw5JEaj0UtBRZz4@u@afdEXEJf4zdHdU1W@c3w9Os6ec90kGmH4evdWtc16Cesq13Rwk@J4xY0Fi6X46uug2fU1aJpdeja02f92indWl41a30RT0PxHN2G4B23OxX9YAoymeHarldLgoaZBLH2Pcu1aX0B807XdVBkdGomaDU4oL@labkK5E8cuaMtNV8UiNBQZJDz8FZK2S50PN4WdHgVNbtmbhWLla5o2KbubeUrefQ24mUUW3m50hc/ePjgfhCMDkBEMf1gK1eGAHiiGJ79s1Wq5PPQhnk@06AxtvDbvKxHF9bWoAM09a4Ab1xl4QtqqVWh8ddqyeSWpqiCUtHkEhdmdkYwp@oIOaWwJVeCeTKSPdtyXC/Lc/gJ0bgUsAAHSj0n5zYleBMoe1zyAfJLneyYfRM7AFpyyqY0wjoBRgDVwdgBY35T6oDRAmN5U7LAOK5rirwpjcFo1HMKuBqslmBpEKtbgzgxZxlMdharS3agnIUdesVxHfOCq2T1rHVGS67S6/UuNs4yMwunnwnMBmV6IejZzllsrQpzcBUyzgrWzBNc9B5UkbNwhUuFV/MlvtqozuzFAl9tXXDbQ7Nr6fj556Z8dj1UASQthjUBETUJd1HxXDeodMye65kzQE0pRIAsQdcBcvxFHF1TxhjPrkdXmAOanM2oF1OtY7vGcRgT/Rzisrhyef6CM0JyeGb3gkWUrWQjRxaUVg4sLCy2xLNnXGLj4D2tXofaeZYrqrl8Lq9qhUK@qIJUWc4V8iWoHHJBzqsqsIhcuVQuXkDblKRXCfo9NbJ7FrXZCj1RP6VX2DmTjRZJv3pk2WclTWBMJpWughSSeMUlbh28p9brqwe3UiChv6cK9ZqWL4NJQ5OqUVlFVQVVEzRFUDT8v8ag4v/N4VX4q/iEUJrKHeEpPI9AOAa9wCEP8CCRwCVHrks3a90xjRUQuwOdnviz67m@/0@AuaM7x8zrrsWOfI297uv43TF/aAWDFRBPR0PL8XHH1z8Xhr1hBxKIPJ0B3IGHZ7vuMoAiefoEHgf779w/it/Lc/0wPkQdiMNOUYcQR3s7u/e5Arnz@NHdK698iC5PHuzdO4qtReYbBc3HKH5x78GDq9bwlXv89KA3dj28uXuPn@Zmj9gJ97hxObgWgWJniiR8oBVFJtQAyBro4pFB4XB73e1cmdwOjfnCzCij8X22gc/y4x14bA9ohTuKdvXpBBl9xyT4nSazS8c96ZmC4XCBUixz3Ig47ikpyqTr2raO30PvrYHjQPdJxzRR@7VtrIkY9anr2d1Tq2uugagJcZQV/PY0JoK7D0iGY2OAEYDygSfRdvFL5bg8oGOPTTIekZWO8EInNHpWfwDyxKkbAXAdXSdwf94LwpvzV3CzQ8DioG7XfOzr4FyC23mMwxqJEs/v8vx9vfiMoIg0yJayWsXhgzzfxwlj2w@6jY0x6E1ra7kSUZvyrkwXWU11Rap2akQpnNfdbVTUN9pmv1bx8wVlC7vdmpzZTrj@fbNU5XndyQKXzFZ8HKFwrGfEqIIYhOq1X9wgpGmel0qolu16u7qk6VafVqzK3373Bz/5829dfuWzyx/@Fkp45K7rGTouCEfdllBNNVRxRTq0opZL@VJZU0vZUrmUyyuFfD6rqFmlWCqWIYmyUlIKpXxZyZZyZRDNcmXwzZeLoYIsSRtkx8YRsSxTgqWNCqB3DPwE8yYdpREHdS7B1pmQlyk9TRJ6bB8T3oQwPNlx@qYNOHBwLaC7STesGnTZRJGJViSAWScGSdy7tyvfu8fzd9CCC/B2ZZ7voiVfkuXiHZ43qc9uCaVP3mVhSniuIB8wiyzfgdIbMwR4lD7PD9CyV8AZD5630LK7c@8extNDi4rhAeyY@TCLHVmKAOagBTR2iuBFjA3Adlg8OZrQPbRglOhzj/nsgh/PvxMlB30OGBhDcD/K6c4Oz@8zy84O@uzSbOdZQr@Alh168bwHFmhaPN8HQ9@DRs3zHTBiA@N5A0zGVAc3/Ow1nsLuBDrPTxl5kEA8P6HQunHM8@3IHaN5L0xNHqlboRaF5XqbWsr443k1SjSCabFF4/lcbMlB3u7ff08fBF2zz66px94G5PT@fajTk/Hevc4773T6/Y433dl75wC9dnfvgzAzHXudficM2GnD5UKo3fuqfjycXr0g1/vtdkW3l3p9od3O6c4Vr/a0bWIKIdQLSFl49TGiYXsXvHbvt7f1ZUuHKMI28pYhvDt43RnC@47eYV7RRb3oe9Lp8FVoBqCoNFMc6la4@geb5zHwaic71A3PraJ9UiMyXZc@bRTkVpV6kCEoR3L1Av17KXzqOICdPps2JjW5VZvUiiobuOql@OZEzVt8dm24pZTzlTV9S1FzmUkFN8K7vSRJCsoWSSm3N16S1KP0lgoq0hrf3NoS@IbS2ioUnyFjq@BjS1VKlZyskjSzasUKhJGTMiH4SDeKra1ivjILXCxmdEmtFIsg9gF9AhAeOjhk3Cap1KmpH6fTmHQ65gj5oRknU5ppq9pLTbKTGkskmaark5pSZUcXE/kKtlSqi@fhjw08N4UwpH1AOAEdCRedpXilXOIhDZKEqwtxJIwR5ywnly7Ozvyzs@ZFzColMM1Gfd//4tHx0dEHwK1AGpmywbJ6OF76hH12Ploo/s79XXH/cWTDo@7FeygYu564izxuwYdJyJHTEahJ4n3o0kFFjtwgTOC5trhHV1KDdB15ROfNiOFxtOLR/QU8hwP3lMUMgfwqCnA6HkGAXwKwukSv1cGkd0mKporo6VMqTLTr9Vq7NjSHo2AKWYxCfYHQY/JnaPZ9lnb6ZRL8bjsNftbz3GHo0a7JF9DrTRITQSA7INuNvSxgbNeIoDwfut3nasao4sJycqd2B9FU2/DugJJvep7r8aCj8tXellMbO77eM5@YHp6rsP94HYQcPJYk1SNmep009xB6F3WqC6HuEWeWxkfjYUoX6p30ohPOMcQOSKbUF6Psn@EYO6Sc5y@qvRpJPQPQF2D31kmqK95Jb@WqQLE7pJ0GJ/l573mPqKSQq1IVKIW4oAlSSiEF9HSt/gWQzRjqY1KpQGrCIj8GrBgZIIbSoD56emRdVI2aTVICmaQpjXLVfq2Bwc/xsSmAcCEIjfMWThG8j3rBizF0nnVo7tVpQq/54w79OAyRO4oqF6oTcFOKueoAylt/Nql6tdHYM6s2WMNJBUJzrFeBtkBCQPPyPHX5lY/Tm0K@xtyqFNU5ihxtsV2bVB081hNqSk2rgUemkZOz@RJINfliFkQItZBVClktm8sKRXQF@SGbz4IjqGAgGKXsFE8In5UnsqhkFVPJpuTnVvd5OnuckoEOlHjpbODuOeMhQRcoMqyt1A5vPZ1RN4BEXZfomwKtvMBkqpgvoP2AjKzsgGI6MHWbBUgLRNtI2espBFo/Go/2Gq1KZW8y@iJ4pYQXW4VMUc68TKerqbV0zTdf0AmYOxZUEB2Ii5yJZn@0BnU6nHgh/njYgFIHk1JUK41GB/NalLOarEE2rfZ5f5Ov862svFZQoMwu6Pi6QhhnmZ9qAMmJm7mN2qgj2CaUoVJWqxzd9ZAgd7wxnfvQSqpQlvIbeZnNNzAU3ChkkUhbkmpG21qSqWSyqCaTM4U6nazizO4aP5tqo2o2XZabSgLLJsnbar6wxYMAyFf4ssoD2IzjYiqJHKV8g@zqpq97OCfD4TAFyYGafsZdnF1s1rmJyO0NLdvSsyDGGviVNcs4Frl7rtfNko7VJz09wLYscjuQ2/2KyB2CjmdSU2MPT9onLDw9UQSDtUKEFTphFQymAxMUIZGb0vm7QLzuCqVE8B1FtQhB3uIO8UCKTfUZ/orPHu48xt@97QTupiDbb4FfGdxLzx4@ffz08T166MBsV/DnubY5ItEtExOxXU1U6fg5LnWAaDBrFfLm1zZOaBNpDffVk4woiHV6YsM2i6UZnh0krRHyefd0ZDbrz9i7idsqATVHj/lukBZdam1aqKKT93QQKLdIEopc94YNVdVaDbUIYgl0XQ2ZgaqqUoVUtBN0k3Ad6vfkDBK9manjuQxfINOpnhGirN8m9X5mXVaniZM2Xyhr9BCBdl2Rj8la8vYGfr9aIImT47W6upFJPqlomeTdpJZLnKSa6/WMMk1KZCOjTnu42AuXF0lJgFPNjVvaRvJpplLqZytKBp8qPCtJIqwlttvZ7XTZ52hNJokFAq@Vd2o7/YOdcHqD7OzWS@o0PE8i8azNl4phEpvrQDI182x7IXwdZKFnOBl6pdzIz3Ft41LyZDWZOEuSRPIiedFItrjENj35QmUnX5BEfPYFro0LFxJouQJJJ0g6tBXLCT@Vpgsrwpn8t5LbiSROmBPffwWVmpYFbdrROQJfeK4Co0k4buTgjgMcywVRKp/H6eCE9Hzkf6iWtIf7j5273j2TSzTXztdcnOonVZ6h5Mkr590vggoLJZYkzVpiUsuF86lKvS4omyqeGFYkFRACekpBkM/rjJvVqUdBBZ/Lr3wnN9ksgV2VFbCraj6j1uvKBoihidHlpz8MvCk523tv5wFJ4uzsT/78@2rxJ3/@B3QdevKCztiqWjEBkGhUCsXE2dno7AyEwAvml0@0EtfW1rWATJKil4sbYrVCpFKpvCG2pUS4ZzClFJV0whcS4c6EQl5IpRRJTW9oJTkNPufhqUwpVS6BNVo3QZ34Qp5PJ/YOrLyqbG9uQc62tJxaXYNiVeIDTUj82zT9coJLlB4@PycELEa92@9bKjVJUtiOXglk85WwCW8o4VfCGnleq@MCQQXPQokm4TfwRAVcE5OsZ6SNJAFdm9QbF9WLVobO5NNRj2cbTvMKMZpruAV30WnDgZ@54dOfaVIrdfDBGtnMjY98PrWRlqRul/Y7uIpCEOoJ1uraJsnXob5sSJDKjWjinf0EoZm@/Mpvq2rhJ3/@a@ft8/YHqqqWy@WCoiZ@9rPNsTP2zW79ZxDwSXT@HVQiw@piZT1yj03HF@MxB9rZWQ5ulrSceKyCsMMOrTBUbBANnkuMHdTHGHw0coFjFARkUqvvmF06YsGdoERNi7XNTpzrpijYBgGFJEv1OXrEVbrKcZGuw/Q1r29kKQ6ygQcjN1pp7ox7G71APiOg81W5t2eowGEIEplrtH177I3o1uUUDae0suQ2BIEY3sbT/NYAOk3CflsATgx99bWgLMk@pRqVuQme4Y1nA4I4wr0NQcKD3O0poVtHKaTlgKwgIghNJ/XoNiDuFsRtswBt6pqiuWcAWcJSxwI5oMZxb@MOVqrmgdhJrE0AqAJPeRsIAHlIhYitFtkkWpqcWZlMdXbw4AUeOINbcfXoZDwOgyG2LpApDlxFOHAC9RG/Vov1Iixh4HtzjhEShoMtiquBAorBqQ0Feguqw@SNUQGu0wGWEM0auX17lqpazeqmCc0R4j@2RjhWS8vBWZ5WQBZp8reApYJIlclgYb@9WO2A4hmaXKh1AjvLsToXlPBoveA4@L9xpcUaeaWoqEcVMxCWF2sVBpAMAiPZWRkaZLNGFLWYJnHiDUi7QRNFz02Khyeak1ui@kHkeQEp/Fki@vAUMKuj@fHvsN7eNe3z4XlMcJ@AEjamh7EGA50xg/Cj8yCzQHBkevtBFDoOBVmxbArdszxQhenau@hAwZSmpDHY7ABGmg66807NEdz/lk/ji4ZCaAJvHQ@4C@NZo@Kr4UKB@iPXoSfiBciacAMi1AjgURDBIzcwWbLHzil@DS4sGxp4PkWQS9B0sOZjiukJf/QT8zQsLmLreKZ@HNEmS8y@SIxhl6hlkqIVzcFlGk6MLk0D0QR3QINCGndscwhJOjRNeoKAX5GkPgh@4w7OfEsPLahXg3sWdD@OL91lBJZOrWNLOsKTvwW3hwcNUOSABWRFbH5sGRwom2O7S2zXPSa2dWyyaY3U/OmC@IGNQhaUnyxQdnYDYSso9qpaFgfClCyDgrsIryIzlrJzYddS0/T1t6aspdpYoue0B7OgVGzzRHfm6Euvc252bgBHD1OsEVQeUmAXY5YLLZOdS5bEowKTaRFo302lOVq@PgTBkCJOl41SfIJPRxvmwciNPPOE4GAIh30MME2jHSYBWzHk9m3aAdC2By0LDzgMvAqUXAZS4nVTBjS9kME75BbRVA4BIWYEZQkAHFj0tUXs4AdBMR9@0IWCEekcEfIVaJ3DLvjhAWph9cPwUe1GMz1ucla9yVqIDjsdGleNsGYRWfJzFmwdWJ9p1tfAswApXJKStRSfAbQZPs0z1HH4q8FZbecoL6mQ65iyBDGEpAYsVFTQkeXgechzn3PDpSJ3dODOeGI/1nqo9KenpyI9y3PsWaLp4yfOfNfRbWnUt0AcdqXAHI7Cj0BbhjSK8M5MAvuCoTgajLYmKNTWyren7M1xPb8WrmpNJXt@EjvHE/yCV394gvoVJLjn0wp1z6Jf@TNS4SJbVv/UVvYsqn@VJD0YL3mBSAhBNJPsNGtkAVm2Yxxne6fdauhxQhskIIdSNCNHPGHXiyxDPzJZo14M4QbIR2Ovjn1M1xMAJp7NGMyiZjmMIKeRNbSPLFwM75inZMfz9Gnq/23v6/fTRpJF/46eooOTAdniy7GdDDaexQYn7DomB3AyuZhhZRCYGUAMwjZMxud3HuK@x32V8xr3Ke6tj26pJYTtJPNxdn9z9kwspO7q6urq7qrqqmr6bmJpZODUksQesYRtn77AI2wz4hOnex0uWst2qPrCrw6bmu83BAt5Cneue4Fy7l/8vuDvC/i@4O@LoFHVbGvRZpEMX91hd5Dr0atflUQwS1XmjvPkBl8IMsjhIs8gsOQy9A69f7tFqq3ozb9gHIuKMYAnpkBwJ5Vt/XDRumhPPOd2s72VHQCzJ4gQMOIAutUmmt72/Gek/uhmNHW90CvYPki8kXjjq@6V5AbmFeyjP0DEGEyvIeY2HYylPxMLBLLDAAHlMPiIokFpnhqa@36yafoIjNNKBDRmxFoSmTZJX/KTfAfiEpOeCasDamuA8L3fJUATvgg1c/hCS7U6fJi5UEaVTdMdfLBELkWynQRKRqYKrzX7NEgaVum0QhPIjuJqMdoV9R2GohX5pHXzTo6/jv7Tz0a/D/MiHntiWN4w9g19qqALP4gQcroQVcVhURtXwCC7aY@cGexcFZZP5W4NzWxmlZrB7WAXvNvhvHuV0ga/a/L4UAKGxCRR8FlhWSxCF5dFnpY8LxRJmeB@NU9WWypGkPV5AQEYudhqjqy20KstikVeOMRiTbVbDckFIbngKlx6sQbJtqwG2lNVbS84PG2QTjG4IAHw8ryNghg0TQjPvnHQg@PH6/EUtSrVZrDmEBdIHkIRG/ms245tvaUhrS1aEQDIiCsAenzXdcGILnj5tP/LX6OYlGqN4l@SDXitAAajJXjfYB3IZzLSgUHgT2zRPgBzN7HVMhJ5OirA/@X4v4SlXqr/8qsvc@GS@fDLnBX53@/yso2U1SaoJn3kczu4IBuBpUI3Wbx1QRsM7BCa04T2Cg@Lwu9gAZhQMdbgxgglRYrbveYFsi/wFGf2wI8kRQUrJyxRUh/jhcZKnHuUI5saEZQp7Rb0jItJwtzX0vQrK0OwMQpxUj2tiE2KI@mT4KyE5sQswVIKo/F0OLkPATrdI8kbJxFZLZ57BfgPcLAUSCAT2S9SRBvzQdyIIpfX/RYlc5ITgfhUpPI6NohgH5TjCR6vW4nnnkhY30BFExm3UjsxjXC@e3lMEqoPyHnTSQpqWYl0JkFV4R2mwUJIYRA8mvheIQwoo2yqFDFUKPAatwxdX@MsoCuTgUOKmZ3Nv8rtfWtQ7ybW3Bq3vm1bm91iQsASZE/G3vXstvfTwL266YuRmP54ueguf/lZiN0dgWkxt7/h6Mb8XjFL0VgU9Sq@zdFNBRLB7yh@EzONZ5RJOynojgKOBHgq6L4EQb4KBZQJI1wqNseKC9GoMC@OW3vt4gQW4XFr0t5Hs8Z8qzjfym@l8MU3eRNT/WDNVLc1bwNd7rRZtGm8tkGrwZslRenSo8NP2NOMkLlgDjukh6ewdHiB1w2NhiDoEzPdkkIqQ@9AWQGGDSDq1z0b1T5q9lTewiep3kOljKgh5NshCiX@Bw8vp/Noh8Uj1jkm3geQeNwFEgblvYdd9sU2K@2OwB5hKdi1BzoSOOJojsHp72fTzxjyZgGDu0p9QeMY3gwsUHHFU3/YqQuG8R/Xw@5Px6/Fdi73Mp97kddIhtfBIoK5zIudYLsCIqkP2@jms5vfMYxjd7pklz3YzBHWThoBWuIUleP3oJc5N85k4hil0Yh9@zy8AMKZ3Ti9jGHUnR65jV5eE0VQjbtGcoFW617PunxrAN0nv0S@wCtN6J4BmPz4F30Sx6Dq9OX9d5aBVhBQyMbDOdtK3Jsh3s7hW3767mjk3iLBumh0YXpgpbEDe5yxaYowSkgshQvp@@Nrb45TGq3GCNC@xNtauz4ZJrD5dWFkyIRhjAAUGe60xia9CCbQXndko6qViUMAGtIooBCArvWuu869OBiExGfiIGTHVECGrUYm684Ml@bK2EbVFuS6gMA0KlRNwx0GuPmm2hCN2knzQ6leEfD8rl57Xy1XyuLoo2i@qYjj2ruP5JAr3tROy5V6Q2Cc6HHtrFmvHp03a/AiUWpAzQR9MEpnH0Xl@3f1SqMhanVRffvutArQAHy9dNasVhqWqJ4dn56Xq2evLQEQxFmtKU6rb6tNKNasWdSqqmYE9UTtRLyt1I/fwM/SUfW02vxILZ5Um2fY2Am0VhLvSvVm9fj8tFQX787r72qNisCOGeVq4/i0VH1bKWegfWhTVN5Xzpqi8aZ0ehrpaO3DWaWOyId6eVQBLEtHsD1iS9TPcrVeOW5ih4KnYyAeIHhqica7ynEVHyrfV6A7pfpHSwJtVP7jHArBR1EuvS29hs4ZqQeoAuNyfF6v4EkUUqJxftRoVpvnzYp4XauVidaNSv199bjS2BfGaa1BBDtvVCxoo1mipgEGUAu@w/PReaNKdKueNSv1@vm7ZrV2ZsIgf6jg5SnHJahaJgLXzri3QKRa/SNCRTrQAFjiw5sKvK8jTYlaJaRCA6h23NSLQYNAxKbeTXFWeX1afV05O67g5xqC@VBtVEwYsGoDCwBMbPdDCRo9p17jOAFe/AjMaijOtWg4RfVElMrvq4i5LA0c0KhKbiGyHb@RNM@gg60moA3xxkHHHutCW3/11Y2DTmGr0l68/OefPx3XyhWRUOeGieDDOew6ryIHU/o32Gn8j/AzdADQcy6vBx1M7okSu1@NhaqxN7AwTYKJAdoXxj1n1VJ2owobG53O@1KnVH/d6HRM6zE1Q2g8VIOygYKwdk8pU/YRI8rQhoZCZaHAdD8IEerwGxQH@87MEuyITCWZ@t/Q5jqxx6ArZrM9R1ZDUwgCVmIp7MEzdywAWA@XRrLCYkh50CRJPfR7KNmBKqYU@Ey3A6@x51zI9eCfya/BD94ctBewOrMonc0OnDmjAQqqaoYbIQMT/SPtO6B9kSTvOc5Pg1ROb86Z9MwMXvOEHpKyDpWdO6PRIGU@UP3SGUSqp6P1CVk0aqoMxB4HFrB2gYzJ52CSZEKOS2ZGPUvhP505/TEVNmxBQ0MJNUUmeKkQpb7h6q1cG8nKhkKQqHmQUeZ7W/q@@gGV3Nz2zn7k/Rv/Pc8tdBpE/1LY8FpUr01/3rS5AEwwsmwCSYbS3pjNanVALCOB0i98CwWvsBBfU4V79ZVD@zqQBATZa3ukt4m78Wy40LGHdfh1vfT26PzkBJZOxHbn1e7LvX3DP8T83uK/H7Ed8vCkM9wp7OMgp9EnbZYcg@BDM0Vzxw/Ynxg4m8WCGMihBo1eotXMvwuKhQROLEGy1AF218P8ChM0gyScCd1fRebMp4bi19iZKRkgFeqqib0Z2wsS8W2QlYgH5KHpaEmjtsB/ELY//dUU9zskGUiyGPm8AucaT3jdS2AlOmnru9cTPgbBIpmE4mM@FPdpgJdbiXxBHiPSL8nb2iiCYIsDjfOVhp1qAhJPo1gIqYeSdzc08Y6stlK5pLNYePO95Dd4/CjdBch5wPbmpXkDyHji10QdOFB0ZadbEnIbA@vwiFq1dCDQgmBKpGjuSVXVN7Nqs4FQwchWtE6FAe/7Vtlok6gIJ/@WBH2bORVNoQhnX3Ks/A2cG9cdCWVfWWPlb2XjEwzLNxkz1W79NgxV5KNvFVTkDJHpq@hB8P9EmsTAPwCNE6AH1NJcKh5FSYLKtAL1lYgyvFVGDM1yElBTf/UxAHOnD8yV3zFpGVqQKwGSQI7OUr34SE4k/VQMAZDJTfQs0OZvz3Xovm3YmUF1@lvClNXRBjPpjqcpIfcKtVWswE3vtS0Suyxlt8EfpjDJMCu0Bk@hqvgbK26XNOtBZYqo8uK5l2BwprKmZjfxPCOY8MSlSJG8muwBZ@XkLFPrgDy40jacnn/@BGLp3VqL4KbQHI5Ca7@0qilCAehDxGe1nxRh6IruyPWciP8KX6rQJJ8C9N635A2E0gEAPQ3QxQnhPO8JebmfM7/FDWLE0MnxIYAmUs/J9wIb4WOJQHBQy62ZAdLStnrrY78g7G817M8nHGNCPwtClciwj4nEcIK3MwLP0NXU4q29BJRHj@s2s1h2s@Fa4tahSB42S8j6GHDZdd0ZiI429htwtIZLMyM@SKODM/GuZ9IbBPaz4UxaJJTQD83M6WZ5ogVuMxy7Qah5Q5Ab5mhzQf6gLo0deyIdRIaL9J5IAfMqHj1EFia3lsVWXqQOgi8HQBNy8iIiHog9zFpGpZig0gHLIQoOPV@5gFnicjsHIhdMv1t39hPu/SgCTXpOz/fz0kDCCzVI1Ql5zHTn3PWp65FFA4YCLSA@JfJsSLu0uz/douQNe/RLyU4goOOrROBrhJ5g1JPPb8dnUgkVGwoYV7YOzLeXhsFEKm1LRyvf9Sq/vUuoxClcd2uVMfK9CpvEReJi4i8pBXmF6nMlOuITr5v@00d84iv0nOJzD2cPvEH7uRRBEWGUWdFmu7rOEX54XvFh6Mx6uk0UJJmePUXzG6k@7oR4UZkOpRNF1557zhI0gG52uMgSjE7q7@7VpHPsjuzB0B3aoKdheMWCVzx8XNIjDthg5t56FEvMuYi0Qr1l8EzWcHmojb@lxw7@DA46vbkzTelHIPPZsoR5FlCLoWN8PGv19yvi72n0xNmvs7MbVPLryEvlr70r0E3319Z9kY@rzKcFCEAucIeR0xk6JnfQ57GoWnKnKe24QxW4vK@AhuOlSAtb@3y3FuNvgUR0wBvCWCGzcuShdwI1s7UYt3oLq0ceHTN3DutW2cG4VS9Fry0b82TCKvIdnkIURP5VTqtKSSh7C/TqwIflenJvv/yTsQcEvgL9/Is4boljBFri@nI2wJpMyoT02QJcyJ15SGs0rcSwig0HsAuNQkA7iyjU8OflOmrQqSIIRdJpYYUrcUamQPHBlBepDiw5nSVdNJ4USZMcBVAEKeEdL2sZ1tGZVfev0dvBI24Os8vgwnQsIac0pNeRqgtUwhx7IZjTax1l9lB9eMZsbz921CIELEoChnDQkk@mEkpyQU9svtR5Tsda7gwW40SEevJUMunN3WnykdRbu3bEnnPH0bprriPSpwizFWGz3OwRaYtLfFzuG1F8IkwTphidYgMPofpKzz6bR4m4KHZwvhU7ywfosI5mwZmsv6n4493juY@b4g2GlqqNxp9ShDu6fO3771sd6Hhn/QoiYbJ61aEVo4NLRmfJjxqoCJl8Kj2eQsR9EvcIPXpAOWy3B7TTx2ctUaMH8MqBTH0KuQwhPdEN3h47uC5N@xnoSMpU51P@IuULnAtrSUd5@fQlumziBwaIUrGTDuxQbMENBivCRxRr0U910C0wjysRPB2yz67yfJKI@gSjGAdp3GH33lZnmc639xnSwocEWgXfdn4PJPkKi7U6C4KyQgqY4jGk8Hu0sjZdPb5XX9sXKAcQuDZ99q7xCB6kKeyMKbYAG/hH/9RZoAwcNCVrhmZUeCJ0aGmAuQBaymDksLqK0t9wxhwPDyk5jUCB4Ncp/LMla6Bz9F7OpzZWWfSWWMSU5ObZZmI2NKoSMBT/RvLLqciiLimuAMBhjKF@MQ8Q0EmMsMdDgZHTn4c4L4SoHCOoWMzjtISX5GMW@JDEfEeiygI7u1qJXFyJb3UY6VggIFjElwkQAZklvkgABTa6WFy0Ei/j@xOUAIFY8T5THIZCjkqYhv7IMQEpU17ODFaUVl5YOcnB9HFn1wx99Pmbvn6b077mol@BPj6GrXQ@@vVVLvQ11Oz2drhqqCbQw9RbDX0EUpg6wv6q8HX/Z5BLoOZAriTcA03JCEkZ0vcLMxmClgl6W@ZHTxygieNQyRgKHh3GpfOkKir1q8MBayEX9/vd2UWSjgzQE/6re6tiNhQmMvIieTEhR3s27rJCSBJrArd67BZquuRNgYYT8jgB/VbptG5fvG@enOhKsLhcKkejsTPbzeVyyMSXeiiB8ttCU9LQzYZLZ/vXo1F2evv32fvLLK39mIR65LkFpUE7MCQwKbyMOxtwnA3iAEWxdBoIPHZvHNT1r/t9PaAFTyhx8GDYuCT7ivUEbUBD3@nlfZMD7E@CDfaf2EHs3z@FP/tubRY0JRR1DAW1gXoXNwl1egbkwRd99P3yT6oIGC7MypsJ9i2zePgJdxCME6PBImdQE81Ckv0Tb5zRyLXEB8xG9jRBFpVIhZMTvUKOi@AJIxIFXYxGwGGWcG6Go@B8ysMiOq8jOLUxqagd5WWPkQZ1Z1BZTFOJ1g8J2Fagy1vYzS309rVEYpAwpev9I8AyHwLajyo9tqepLtEpWhi2ejmDgyfA6EXeitV9QkVMsolJmj1cGokaj27mR3c4SUHXTZIFVGQADS/1ZE1xn7iJi0W@jzTMMQyJE11n96gad/tftzR@3bJ4M@/3H7cqUlAFD@xnrYgcV/Z1CyKdAdAMlNMP6InRlf9Iw7Q@iQRCsYCDoU@r6w5W6GAFw3jeLf58myqVSuLZdGtLlEpH8ICJfo5Koowvjo5EGbOo4O9vitu7u/u85pbNT/DySL28E0cAgy/37V7NyvATvhUxwA22e9Iin2WLz6z9Z53iweG@l22VjtrZ7ACe@KKmbEn@wBucskf0o/WDXyiTyWSfdT89@@ZuH3@3yu3ks8vWs2k7OdhHLgMylK7nbnWetgP30czs0tjgXUB7S36kSs/2MIurrCpUeoSxPfsJVpeC2Oh62Q351uM4XFpjN7qO9t6ZYCIUUOFVCEdUlTcwRH5sL9EcD6PTddABD/YbSuFKfqBcn89WlOF@4moF/FOVDUJAyqw3DoDGE44ldJIbxviB9HDiORO0gN@QzMvdMwwb/g7nHcm/2R/kVQqbFymxmROblthMJOgPXquweWE@yw7xsg4u5l@4EBwtoJuh8IYk6JH@QJGLEXIbxjMKgERIKhyaCk@ux5dofFbaH4ZPyvB1b2A8oQsm2URCh0xYZePTs8kdDMsnKHGXMJ5QOGMec3@woNCRWgw1pp2o@OOLIpDtsSNA0PKYCVJwoUk86YPKfOaXVW/kWBsUm0mAkaz11yc07/EF7EXPKKYzH9GlMGiUgh/5Le6N@xy8S2jjF24/QIAOVFidzFHYSHIjiWcdlLHf7yV1U1CMp94/yXzs67B05lgxaP4/hcYE9OmJTrhnE3pH55j0kemfGPrHK1pTCS5L0fZ8MmNoVcbXo/lwOpJnXkQiHDm/tTueSTiiBIjhcAR1YXWGkaEAMx/cOhSGrA8Lhx4vRc/FrvNMkKlWcTqYGT450oiQ/SEFc/vXyNw2s0PERLED8wAh5bvy9e3hyEOSz1XO1oE9u8RcC5SfWQznfG5G9jzMqxPB2O37SGcIMrmcB/MZurIxndmDsW2JjTO3ObOXVdi2QPKZdzMm9HCSnBMSOPlk03HdUwhzj@SQEEX8rpDnEEZvj5Yy2JzHFkeDBoOGVE0FmaABJ0GInYiSzq@hsYrQMeDqzxgEHeWVxds/jZRLLK286GkkIQVdgH9omq1MHUO1oM8df@IkDEbVn5mKF2Sla9xox3TwCys5JvRWbVNNR54PClgusX3cnQbOxA5tTtORYXBikmfZfcH7Is5nSuzB3kjyEqD8y3yQPwCxAjnyh1CCG5npwu2zzGY8SaWeXHgyOH5D30dQeM74vvhZG1lVnpVTOPiYkvKdT4a8WEZ2qCHTHpgwI6rk@Q8Q@iN7APgtb@0lsuLFRuq7p1mz9cPFpL2Zupj8evGLSZjIJVntsmmxIQ@z1Yol5wrsjFkr9FN5pXnyJnpxMQkXuJiQWxef3ksSACLZVOuHbPvXLCB0sWGam9mLDSZIaMgQk@z97WURfHYFzY0wFtkN44m5aarBT32XNwXsrfQXx5BfmPwXsFBKJZnpQc@Z9QEUxQDRDQSo2GVfbed2tvM7oAkNnEV65lzjfpv2ri@dBYgSHqqzsPVc/BLihhAh7haevQ8vF9DP4WCCaaBpRD2Z0EIuoXKaUzuGz1ZQJ8M8AeWByikkAYa4mH4ZGw8fUeG3BLCcKksZLdh1UOO@FO6fnjvGdmwP17VodAhzJHoZsI8ImVDTCFky3loONdV0SVKwWUYcXzkwyAgEhje7oe0WE3eSlsKamUnuoxCNUTMjzO0bnaMrUzQ0Q59JYSr5VOQPv3v53/@79vPGfONwO/thBn/nGz9v7L3a4Ed4gF8v1K@bjcONAyy2d7exzIIODI8v//v/QP3DvwMc/LI8gH8OdxWsveXGYbpIVX7dONyDh/z2NrT7f//rv6APz1hjw8w2zzqWIMT2FUWO7QnxLnwXVewlq6XJYFnJ48KCMNjDEHRz@IGOUYvtVzky021Ir4obdP8Z9ue@P4rc4skxa06uQmzJUP4UIBlxhSI2kGaQyoWiLzTfDeW2gcwboCn@@Tyz54EG8E/pzuE36btuPPfQZegZq0UwgCluEfR5fjjMfZfw3TsKCeVTsq9ESFTt5Fr76sU@sMM715kPu2EvCTVdx1371rnMIB9mnN416FQTb@T@OMveAEuO89uvsn007mfJjzs7JUjp6TLzCwiCMhsJKIbkdGqJGYyAO4a/8Iw5SkCgP/HPpFR2DpCyp06XbVjhDE9QpNEsV@p1i4@HsTuZQJRO0b8gwGMeEplWQ4s8v5hAzVq9IBJbfkEuRzqvidi8I@dYmXQkzd6wlMEWBBjqA1oHVX8ypdmAgpCo1gwgcJGM3et1bPktZTxJqMBzy3hy5YymxQT5hkFv8LIykNAl/VnMXAslPUQLQjpNCx3CGjtzG1T0YoLeoD4etDDH2wn4rJV0Y1pdfLL2ZVmp1feKJ3imdU/Tt9z0LYwoSglBOz7PBLlwJkIvxmtLEU2VM6eDR2qxDUNrnkqBNcvQH8TA42Gp9jEsQXaHIiCBakF3pFeZPmwW6cLAI7cOx@yxaZHzgBkbQfCjpUoAZ1XPMig7YbsZbgwWiDN34hTQQ5kvlcMIiKJK2jKckAC08lnFDksw1Ifa1GE0FaGwI5bcliawH5LAgbGUAkgwdDze1AIfbIN3Dx@0hKMl9Emg4SVhIkv1C6RsUUE1HAVKqsWNo2bGdqpWV/jJevoyFxBdl4YvErn89oud3b2Xr77FmPEnsrfxYLBSBrWA6ZUNMEiiToGSje@LxUQywa8woddqkwg9DiwewKFb161JWPHj02I@J4HlEgTrlhJTcXVpriSQAcSZk8EdAXSU1CyRSn1XaGHH2hc981f4L2Gp2sxwaGq2R8NfbCa9Ng7vOCCC0hyNnbE7w@NxXJhtyuyCefVhC@EvelnH7dcdvJkKfV2Z7aGhU9fFoISZez240rkjw9Z@0YQJAwSfz5YF0qBeOxwpSjq1hhXKotLgUNWiL4oKXmu1B@iUi1sCynwMHKYZTAb08relpynOjiRsQpjnASNW8QhRcx3V2Zm4c@KKylk5ipjMhDb0fLgZ3bMVhDvYDwF8pXaCmY@07jaBujAlBrLXak2y2KBPuq9c4HJYDrgCmR5jpbuY1kujilqrSW6Yp@4jS554cegntAuqwjgiXjEw87mHSaniWlUvkCBqIZTWJH8Rs/zzHJ1kAU76IOM8RV5OFDQf0bdDz6N83rKxhCk9SqkQDKTHpxJxANFuk0twR3IFHFF6rFAaKx5tvkKVXCbx2lEeYF9TdWJLDvvSVEBR45xZxKcF9r96dmyJcgX@OflQtlBQPir9A/vtJ8xaj29e4psviOqJGgIiqDTDkc8t@kz9jCFKwCw5i9OXBAji4kuGDaxHkjdSsFI9kbTnSd0Kze12wBXIrrYUwpV1VE4SzJpCNpAnUnkn05nMtSgV@gIbr1ZXmi1ZWE0LNnHdP7E1mjwJWvUhMSkfAWI7CiKtQATc/iRgePZAJ8nblrqLYuzqSTxPh1iWFSoQ20@yQPYwz66lzH1ssS3ZYruA43gfXxDf3ssbfG9ZmDke4I2nX8Yb6cczR/rfgjkqfw53vJDc8aKAaw9zx6Q7c2hFoohOSmrnxnDM5ZL24E5vOBiifaiv/cRO5CwNAC14dB2ZTfEg@Rz2bc1yIlLxH7ai@xE6CW3v7hlf2Pkd2fmdAq659Fh2/qd2Pv0bd35Xdn63gHtNzMhL0U6Gv/52PQ5EwlT4RezworjLxcwv7eme7OleAXfTmGH@w3ua/p16@lL29GUBMybwgQOncL2fm1kSKTWOq9XA3SKjMhCnMCtgPFeaqHvhTdOW6I@uvasiSuvii/F/JfF/hasRPdWRrLYWo@zr8qyecrA8S5Z8aR4GWXFPuL8y1Evvr9ywAn1EblC8SJNhayYVFRDILf4YnDZlAvkxWH39zeexOPPaTrmVODOspkCzRpg3gynOki8VVglYnzAjz9GSdtysn279LybD2P5JRqEB8ji0t3jPkNxJdBUMx4pfy85o3UHYDalzhFhFkpOQnctob59dnqxf1SixRWRfjFcS@KiN0yVjBipH8wAikxHQJiPrK60KXXOVesFvoO9cKL7LssdfxKXfSi79tiDqUjFYRypbGvwkLwZ62vbu7n17ANfK4B@cgDkLyt8zq/5fcLiw6v5R6iN1Om8dz9vQkkUZep5uLiOwjAiXKV1DmVkBr4yZXKL/wXs/@dS2oWVbBmXFM4zjt@UG2i7sy27P6Q@uhj/@NJ64059n3vz65nax/CWfMAyVnD9lctZC5X0jzRSr@ZoTs0QkaXNay9ocgEDDfJKtJmFDSDKfT5qtQmG7bQqcn2POx8TnAwEAElEn3gjvSSI3Cz97OA0lezBEY3s9Ovr35hhzDiRLjezxZc8Wi4JA/@t03hLoDSbfdoGQQCKyw6S6sHpOTdOke2HklRNJHXIhaek/9a7OBuMq2@dEIiFRgp9VOhBAY4tf1LfQtMjk0habwHz8ZdgLW0rYJuPXlKn1UC2QfLq90zYLQKYP9AUZ/soezflEMPWL6XvCOHM/kgC3zmNe5HAXyZmhwAUN6QPaAP2OmZI5glMu7q@2roa@a@34MFoB@HaocIhW2o8tmPp@6A4Ag6ngHrnu6BTHV7VgSWpY4lXQmSATIoY1v7FHfX8UVLbiITtVhngn3EfKIYvUDg1MhBCSGH1/pQuCqa@wWVdaiv36eNgAGF@Su8IKKB1frLRSYIVLaA0N5fShTSNaj4fXm3M68ZhOBMzZ8pGgHNEBv2nvN8T3tTqM/o09G6Jhi61teWgj42Rgfg7I4X8uJ1NsoiI5ubZ3YV75kGmGmSvIxfdpHcqp1Zeg98qX2ACtO9gBvDhXdQF3swFlN3wY6UegfM90DnEog0X2PoHtyGdvxdT5PSnUJZOItJQf46ZdmLuRtWfoY5x6FRlsRQecXntILvWizfJK8PkVjjPmHIM9YGazO9mGOJ8PYRFfBj7NJNyQw5guZVESIgbGufmjE7h7ZYlL@UPm15GYaosH0oby9F@ZQaLxNZ1TwFrsjrElXuKZOzGEDxEEOJwBeTNuRcTG/J9ZsW2u7y6Uwn56q4JlpMuhQY3vrnutI5B7sJ9BefUEe4i@jq8QYtgOs8AqBLXUStdh3Bvkp1XOxiOpTgdz/3Q6lGql00H5odNJcissTGhCkHbvRemydz1Lz@yrsW1P/p7tel4aL92ezg2jC2Q9OBDJylk5iaFW/qfMdAnjkN5MC5mnX5DIgW@MRCIcZXrcaIjGcb36rinom0Fj0nVHI0eKB1JGqs16eEdoedidK7GJpTz1a2xjWiGDLqUUx57XIFy4hzi4nQ66/3c6Kc8Z9bXR2Qie4L83zbenokkJB5uVBuVDbMQURRgZDIAk9RQRP3harh03P76rABXHo0PjQP2BQodU72A@nI@cw4Ms/@V33nyJosBy6oAWKN9l6SXUzXLlg0u3t4Q/veGNoE/FhDr6L8wcELeGN84@VNZpSwj2XXceIJiF@ghUQssygqqCXhkEuVq5JgrC7uGRDQiCSnnASeVhYMiwvxTJF8nM0CO9PmWGW5Y3n0hpNMk/M9hi0hLJ261kzNYfHojGmxLQ8vVp7ah0ihm/3lXqmMZy3VhcDjrANCjB0rUMyfBXDk9zJyGhgr7MpcQa/Rgu9T2JxuF3H8Pv1nSjXnldxXyO6zFnkhbFp1whfxf@dIM@VbFf6BIK@na3isEaVE5OS6/vxQKVupV9j76ihTn265qmameva5iCElNnrmvRnQxA0xh0sOUY8qrP2HQHL@rwHkVv1fJRrXwPzQcj7ky0UWwMp8ejmjqunZ@tXxyki3A@DGXD8BE9b747bxrhmv5iBROG1ilLLLSlSpta0idlYa6Df1RqVETllDKeap/I12XkjBV0SywtXlRABaW10/FAdLFUokIUYwrRuGa6WjV2ObIvQX@@njv7GAda@HQ3XezP3al8wKmGOX4LHOua@nTXcwbm/oXx6S7BbRcTwNCJw093vFhdTJJ8Fc08JRHVJ/MK3j7SphEhRrlSr76vlBU9GtrnUEkgWvVYffXp1R3Ouhg3p1GM8s9YMvtMzAilVjZh@kKUZwhJAsGUYTD8jH5Xgxl61aZpksPb/UsXNz/YhXvDa6@wm3u@79NFIrLSHIO09MUxknQ9Rk5QHUbvsj@xu79Z56gvCLt@b4dArAWt9HKEiSvgv9Hv3sELQ47opTufu@M0pbVWw8u1Qt9xMoU@@wBgcq2vjR9jqkZ78iXkXiHZo3hLTTNK7XxSPeZNvgFSf6ler31oRFbDFb60ZzP39nz6@7CmyKlxgydJQVrFBNJNwLo27IkLg1YxusBu7s9LrqUViynEQylLXRhcTmd21CUIEzO7TRcRBr@@ajIT0cru7eRfkmy4e/yuNAvTqY6V/jhCBb27h04hzllLKI3mfzh3nULb/5JE01nwd6La@jWPUrbfu@YFAkyz8n0zKrQg@eleap3y@OLLCL66/epdCwRCamENe0h8fbTj1bd7Vvj@cDRaJ/j6Kt5iVV6WEuWampr6t1gnL9crjdrp@4ooV19Xm@J96fS8EhGbZ3g2dOPwQbZsauYM8EIIoB@dUGkNJzUFoouhFRQHx@dYFOyGp@FoM@r7Bk1L9B0OBxnOkx6XNXSLqp/vZ@JOnNiWVBOBXl6IS/EUBQ3Vkr8m0XpFX8J1bvF20KKEKw@Efk2aUdM7FJNuPUk0zHCwBHnb4nWreI/lqkF4JG1oPEoh@gaURcD5trm6CF09tvZ2XG1JishRIUg0V2bEPB/unAeK3Wrntlc7BwT7qu5JBNGulYFGUwDvfsy6rveHIwZtPowYaIV/NNUwqiVEOTOiy6@eUJALwjoukQ23aBaET8Nk0Ns/nCVFUq2FcaYm7cqKAsvag@vJY6aofo4aHKQunqISb61MYPOhKXzsjlaHLL@2f8nZ4BJ0eov@3/R3kdizeOu@Sy7ij@@tNaf69wEy7xnu2KUwsilUz8qVd5UzvJJG/KPy8UOtXkaTcCO6NciL3yND6HtikwnV023OuoFVVeBilI1i7qp7okCOuRIjtwuzAkeCjGW0Ey@Co0YGz8Ev8CBvXg6dFKuDeFomyJyRDFNjBQaziVhd5@mYmTuE4HZW@YEyad43ebk6Xk@xUnf5yLr5mLqYn/6xbW@vqf/Y9l/E1SfLLBuLpL0KMeI/yzVCtL9e6kOEBph1A3T/JF8ZPvP3HUDx7zeCZP36yvFTRqc/ahBf/TWI/v9dzh5ZeSeu8uiRlXdjKs8f2/JeXOXHtvxyLeP6ps5V7rVE1GL3Gews7W5/rUh/0oqk7J73LUrxg4Z2v7@G7c8cNrK8fv7AkSHyr5H7M0eObcGfP3RoDf1r5P7MkSN79NdJcGiIjAwiGUij@KHqHsUu3A67V6BdkwCEP94nQqJFM4JCYM10Uo8gk/nYxlCd/DKF8Et1vS9lNHbaQau3NFsL5bEuGavQXtfrsPfG@9KpeFsrV0/iPDhWCOQ5f9iU3iZF3ydbYMnFj@R9E2c0m3XYtPxoqopYIOgk6I85hvfHTjL0S2qp4m2yDcv2Y1yt2V/Wr2c@wvdZeu7ezlyMP/fwhiUV4j225xoH@naUUhkvVT6tnddhYOuNz5joPff3GVh3upaObOL8Eu6/YQd9tQZGOclfXHlSR3smSyFm8HkrGe@grZk6KZamP3LtADV6i0nu@fWK6TfcRvpr2kg/ro3Nr2lj83FtZL@mjWw2rpE1y1K5cnT@WmRF403tQ3wZ@uJd4QVReLtTd@Y4k3VLWHgNgzq/D6/HWs7/NCtgZIfwR8OfHZFKD9rv5XL0E0gn/j0W@iKkDQ4PH4/OcKJSKD9qeOgCtD9wfD5nv4gbI6YKH1P8pvRcY4s/q52lyQAfMsTzHfa@Z6tukvc8TBIorfKeez3r6ucplJoWx4i/BJlpUyuRU/fuYHibUtiBlkN8MM5L5Xug0FehMony3SDxfMuOqVsw4LGNBH64X9OI7@W60k5oYVLiCXHnxSR@M4nve@xiGXg7t1YcgNutJGKUbCuGJELEgtnQAaXTaazyKcmMmix8ugOZkEDB4916PGI8gGNxjfV6Xim53pd5le@D5s21BF0Z51h4kZATH/iq67S5Jn7MnwgyR3OIPeQ5El0eoV8kUbj3yG0RSuUcri2Slh7Js5acfJwWyJqWWMAShP/GLfiPdhmPnQiPG@B4x3DtmjK6TNhYO49ouR@pw9WNmLkUCyNcLU5iw5NfIHg8tddsjhpfrwQjEkdILYDP2FeOE@/jfKoax9YPnPpH1oe@UiyCiY2n5/7UTibv1qwNPMeovn95AlLFAqKbcXGKOm6H61AjJEjb8SRdQM9cXxILafFKKXPt9J1S1rkA@vq5JXfiKVLlzJ04X0BC/vsgEWM4MDyBfX8Te8VGoillfLRNYkWaxAoKIPLPuCk7IaH6tTwdZtd16LCOWBL1SqksGs26ODk/OxbVs0YTX9RO6MNp9awSc6qzjB8WfftTBG8pareD1I@PXnnDgHhD/FdahUmbVwSXYy893YjZ/bF/gMsfmGNE@1C0VhxlUbyMJ6waocLDNIiv2ALY7UARH7bvBTTknBj/BlwQT437@eJBbUDTCCau8K4xqRduJs4CdBAvaT52jWoVdnhZwr36N9opNQEhdqdcL3bELEZx0vIae566EuMzBo5JSPfBx8gWUs1Ut2QYa@cdFcivsfsFbk5yQYh6OIWGJ6K/lY5g1S0dNytl8bbSfFMrN/xPEWdejNONRumuhr5pIbhmJDg/eekMrifRGFMKfZv0HgmZY2djw1ozlKspPuQ10x25QKMVjOj29@TaaL3j0ulp6ei0IkkTDdhbOF2px2LO387Unl9Fe8BqrIq49YvBbj9LRrK/vEpG0dMhRLpFgxF5F9KtZb1IESS0aTwUec7x4oC0H68tmwoS42jlMkyHILWNaWBmUcNALhDprkjn9YD0p1rUMV2nI9Om82sL0yNNnFuaaraflNb4nxDI/cjwypyMrszFBVfmKLaSnfopJHo/iLFMHO7kdmU8@ENx4UximeooHOQvpu5oORi58AwPQPFsz7nJTq5HIwO3/N6w3w8Pgv58@M023ojpdK9cAdj8fw)

Python 2.0.0 is separated from Python 1 with `'\x161'=='a'`, see [2.0 whatsnew](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/whatsnew/2.0.rst#porting-to-20):

> The `\x` escape in string literals now takes exactly 2 hex digits. Previously it would consume all the hex digits following the 'x' and take the lowest 8 bits of the result, so `\x123456` was equivalent to `\x56`.

Answer (score 1):

## 441. Python 2.2.0, 19050 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPZdSD4saPT8yMuE6wCQCDfeIMAyWKxutiql0hWd7sBFCqRSADZTGSiMhMkUCQrujUOrWTJHluWbFmW3bK8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsank94djYBDLzPs@999xzzz3nvrKj@4Of/SyBF3ni2tO@7QYkMP2AdD3rxPREcmdKtnXLz6sax2GoHa8/HppO4Fe4BFEIsXWnP9b7JulZdmB6WeKbJumYtnsK/iohm2Nn7JvdOtg0QhzzlOw7htUFCCRwj03Heml64Jcj5K5pnw/PA2K4w6HudH0y8iwnoL55Qp7oYOmNjWOid/zA043Ach3wKiwkUVywlQh56Hq@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@lDwEbXpDh9b/8J8Q3XAxvcGJY1rJvAGHpANjdJcu/R3SSpx9Uieh0urqIaOYMqSESe5ES3x0Ah8zXhQv14cWwOqyy5lqyQJKBFlUkuR3LQfktEzQOSFLkMBmAEqqbAXSBqieQUaG95okFgTYXGXQAfaBAkJ4NjOZnF9Hue3rdsk0HvI/QiNh@IpsJTzhENWoZW0Fjovmv3WFCDZqRItBIpFEkxT4rwLJOyCjnBZHPQaPJwF@AGiGXIJgBSNci0rDJgs3YBdIy0uEt6@tCyp2EKNAmD5BVSBKhQHgWgqyWAAm9Nw1uDu4TQFq952MEAamOgnwB4wbaOkZ2ZMUfDKpbgJW1sSJR1Im9myfsDTB5QC0jNl0gRki8ARnKQBcC8WoLkwVPLQxYghJYvQME0uAuscP7AtO0Q1MBHULQERRluKE0R8FOCGoOaUGVEdBFusANHVYF1qsAnVWB9KrArVQWzhslCOKzCAlR/IceSGej@MSTE0lG7tFKgOwAwCtYCskkFEQcQoCYJoF/DjJKchsQDmYcyQV6KBQKEUVJIKUdKRQI4LssE6kyBfCFlKcChFciPgsCANhQgDgXypEANKABU0fKEm6sARUN/iKtBXECXkoM4OTBDZSoFvCEeUIwCSSqQpqqWZ4QLeVPzUN68RilaLUCNF8EP8KZCXlUgMyRjtQT@GLcEOCwhwReTWYYIHfEANYVNBOgTkAHVo1C4EBbMajEkaN0eDfQO9gcsZqeHUQvYdAqIRogqY/HgnUNsQlagllVsIZB9FahCoy0M3rk4eVsBIA0Eb3YtytRt7FiUGEPFLCXSj/RRMEObUqA5Gk2DQeymMjcXmK0FDNPs68Y09oSWmY09Z64FDV1Vyp9ngOQcuvrAjd2xb8@AxIacSpMyTyx75laibl1T7/Ysf/BqltccTaRj6oFjHc9Syeezc0jV5zwK6LHgVNTmwwaWAF1cf4CmWVnUIoYZuXEFLWRZUWj2OmZv7PRNoVyayx/1CcZeAJ3RLM0yc/asfh869hkcJUuLSTvXmXOe5tDWNOjzI0fELqbpWdDl3ybGAESW2LPM4JfLMxiaijCmegclAQFEOOg5ytjX9awJ6dw2aE8zy6BG8WQMrFEUuLIy8Fzl0kQmpcIcbVDMvSzJMcvGqyV@5FpOKkmSae6Cg/6JiaXzvTt0gu9jz4Z9NZIu9MUulTRmLDXlRL1pGpC2KBhAT22jANUxDR17bezDTNoHR3CsQCSQCMiWpnuCMi/tSBeS8Wln2/FQxAXJqGt6HsGwIBf7Wdot@@OOb74Yo@w1y1cP@nkTxIGebtlxBmjfogdUaIB30of0povZ7nnukHZAQ@x2bdcdrRBxoJM/RUD33VNzlvWZDKCPRjZIWuBuMkEPMnOqU2GdSvbzqbIMQSSMBxUOAGlSIKFYnmlQ3IdFh9gayDKLWawQtX5bQyh35kQwDRoLiCc@xnHGtl0B2cg0iFaXuuaJhC5MTFsUzzAPkeAG4lcIoqODNI45p7mIId1WRSoSHkU167vDxaKxPnc/LvrAQmHKPtWnUHs96G7NiT4EnYGgYA4tlwyBYlgNYk2AcoHF2idd10kGMZRTDwRfKHRcEipcI04Ca2iC6uRCFKzxHM009vg0Z50pkDLFVk6kuhLLyRVEidxVRDGH3JwDaywgInbHBmIN07YcSkEgQvmoF3jAKpkbF3ik2dTh9kAGHIXqoYgGDHiIWZvTMnzW2kNp3aAQUa41HR8UF18kFipvQPl9twfEdmpB2YFhQdQZbIMiAVEQO01EQ@QoypGAhsc2sYgxGhFwh04JyPOeXAKx1f3IIi/B0x6A2mGMPW9KJiOoCWsIoQLD7fWAel@aowGAIMMuMaYGNE@oZEo9/sDRR1zXpWzGGC0WdmZbNyGMg@rM7pNfJH0TkA@ibg@VSST8WTFGI1oQihDdYWKwowO@sCDGaEqRwyVmMXquK6J71zV9SjKudxwzAEzMN/u0gUBr681Y0hDFeqBVh6ojXeA/YSND@Jggt7QwmFRIC@@YDjQgA2gTmj5UItbsDumBnj4n3KKGohuGOQpCanEpU7OcOU3h8T3UFKirEAIT/QG3vk02r9AOBI3pZ07KRc0Jsz4KFRgdOW44GCBQ8SNWVhl/safXkocQJ1dS559jmIUcPOdX5GFEGwaqTZRVjANkKMgjLWOAHDFAnkMlcWhz3vh68cFtPnlvSIRenDbmRgHmw4lS7IT5WA1DgNu@Dkgc2QirvuCAQRccXgNa94dLILtxJu3uvKso6SKwxtcBHbqOuwQqIDOGi0EWfWhdUGI8RN6h2zEx0ubiL9QRsu3Z@BR2Z9CTjkauBy2DsZ4pHYOgVTZHXaHqnop7jLRI7ix2sNBxJLHbD7AvhAgjWwdawCaGLRV0Lh34BbAyploD53NZinMZpq2ewgrzd0o7AEZM0KM6jolqm@5NGRAoHnTSkNCUWJ4HzPAEuwrWE0VdikjpFHoGvdtF/orooO3@auIiUvTuuGNNrurvBjqKH/ncie6RHqruHoge0IhSyZ6fTFepO40558VL7iiQaFT25CEgDSRClad6vohdxT1gNIdTx0jxC02MzxJ@HPRKfBoMGJFJauRdUBiu5g6VCCSa4TG0a2qrkj504oIATwHdaE7QQxLRQ/dA2oBGCLpmudzt6OQcuIdHhMkuU0gixUQRc3FaptON0woRgXmZL6/IkvA9gxqEub4NS4DBaclpJ7GAwDfEBI3Ig4MkhT0sOlCZj/lR6YY5jh063kdSTCBJk7NYBIYOIEUzY4EIYhlW0A6Fltu3I/FlrVYDYgOZCthmNz2v10ZjoSJwaggsUpkkTEQM3MMA20YqDeXFwBcsNyA8AaXW6uQsGHjQ4qj9goNAgFbOQUqOEBvW8yPreNy9WtEOOmIgHlsdiE6WEfBVDkQA1hpqN2E1uYBV0H2TiFUkXoxPQV8jXuqKFcqHwTzTRyG4FmZlroZTmIOQVpeiiEUN3WYEvTs17FAkYCZo7IwbdSD7x@EQWMyIsqFMEDXaay2VAcHmwOCQJztH92thW2SeUsdyKgsOtmvoNnVex@B8FPfB/p2DnYNfbC@BYVudylUHycqVCtjVjidC3xlLOVGtrM/DmAG@274ZNkZcDMNzoTcR3MmcqDQ1oHOZROh8fPCFqygBSQjRQVMAM95XRBoWBoQurqP7gyudMOlnMpBkHCUKS4R9EsGMDZh19Nej/DwZv3yJlXc1U6PQHXNmj3UGIHKU9p0onoieVwSwyKvTYz0ijQuyqOXg/MbMNB8yys87KDtfzQwVqOdI5p3H9/YOahRsOLom0CCSH4AspXtdEWjeHoMiviwMsD8wGSQjzjKOUjXN61IEG8YCgmd1S1bABwCo8YguEexhVDR/AHnfvVo26ioYMQVQO4VwVa6cl4eMz5vRuXxgF2eg4rusF6Ues84qdlraY8W@i92Wkc@bxVx5vtsyZml254HS6QToByK50QOvY19AF3EmRYZidZj9wwfXMu5TIRJUASHKmW8Tkabl2xxqL4JFkr60C3qaa5vi@5Tj8YRPS1IymlEQDZ@qoHPh9yZWkJLT7K2kISykvrOzr96NAoeD2XQ8gyoNqJFjz@T1cIrQ8IFGHNd2@y7ZgDhMOowSBLFpZTF3@q5zrYZ0dMSiJnCWEfgvDt/oI@hrrJdUfaSx5pVWNl@pO/4pcGmloCGSKIYoKImGFz/ST3RA16zch/sf7kEnouRlOTbL9AIUzMWh6EKTMedKHYgACYlhfpYWMJ6WvNbaIw9hbl4QCx0yujjizsx7qSPlmKK0NPzSLL3rXsP4R@70CmmBCyMtMMyhbP/Rkwf7j/Ye7nzQDNR8fsGek8sFQByk1wFZSBwwvGFr3WBNE4uF4BLQNjxsXsAFxqCgRPNMY98Dxi1iEJFlYAXVsAnd1LvuwEn66auFOUVf4SPHYCT0EBsfCxpGBEW7a6My4rEJb@zPkX4GQTDyK5IErXww7oigtEofGa6t9yUaDzoG25YUVF32H@Pohr8sBmTGn5osBhviAtFhSscRdXvogvJCp82RNZAUA0/HrmyrPwBdGOfWTS8txhRMSyN1QUMAXVmKy0YZMLUBbsN3VE88I@23FbXE6FqR1ZzER8EWmj@EXeuZoDqloLcCVKSvWEnzdvM2mQKXRkhXgSSIuEEHOXyCfYFNQJCkY6eo50fIodwCR02RV1AcvRjjmC5wKSkv54pKIS@BWgZqGsisAo68CUM9MAZC4AoAT3B7dNxgjgp7vqE7PXEjNESZBbnvFhRVazxrNp0WCOjN2zRvOGPdmLYaSitdJdejbITh01Wg3oXiIe1GDkC71AikSd9kBT/r6tfZWVenratLpGA4CvscYUQe7oAg9dIFft0159seRpDmPaWNhbASBn4lLRkQsjEqhw/ElAQNCnpaID0J8yWA0IviIVAO8K25CGQ2mhELTNNgAPxDI6ldakpfl3DRWQu5xmJWcGhYHE2B5dFAyLQFDTMUedAERwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwlHHrD0EVQTG9DahY4A1DkfhyID7IJxzmbMxoaxSYZWHPDcET4kuvDyJuEiCg2AL3/4WS@EE4ttIrmjI8UBFq5IdmFEkTxFFgB9@ZQEdKSha6Iaj8smnjoWKiIiR30F6LqS620x8NYID2ld/vBPLz/57uXXP7n85FuXn/z65ad/fPnpv1sTXqGOWd/MNJuCmG20CJ@8lvlbe@qtnTu37pRoDkGehMz/X7/063/3G7@ymPcl6f7446/9@ONf/ttf@eRvPvv4xx9/6Sc/@vpPfvSVn/zoq2@UrvN//qpr/NdP3DDJUxwamU8wTA@SGwygF70PUltj49bpGVlbW4Poa2tbUBNrW1skQ7bgKcBzDfrNLfDNwnOLNMB3jbTIRYsDDdYnS0b7RDp@Lpq6MWgDtzTMlJYWocs7O5@ck8GgMRGhnR/zxgbfuqCzS7QvwBkXluldrLRDunIG8/4udN/MNsv8qqQbUrMhN1vNs1Szm0k3L6Ss0gItu23hw0@p6YYiigK4IW9JSeJZ6UKK8zahISGQaAy8Wc7ohB1byIO6NCP4e9YEeiJglUBI82PylLXQyR0cWv3QHA2m3nyAeLwK5FMce56tD8FlNMj/5vnLSxZ/XhRa0JEjiZGFA7EQh71Q0hhNGV/kWE6b0sLypKjHOhF6QzfQpfdEUDfEuY4muZaUBAH6EOrDINFiP7R8A1QL3THdsT8/Rrd06BBTB9ejwRjY9@7AGnGmMXCB0rcBJolnSRDJOOEjsGmjKFrXEOHGZo0sA6cYoDemS3csqHzaeukohkKTPtFtqxuPZecLoxdinFqVxiEyJmT1HdczBUAExODoOiW6DI6rR7O5@3Sk6BqvDH1pF4B81zKDLLlnuzrFqOsALcxRI86FzOKDPgtRDswuZztE6IFoIbIa8MyutMHRuU3XGwC7hNLglI0a19Ew9JBcf9QVgwlE5VLYQc17Mm0IhLRT0lVVtWDke5XID2kBkD2AqkEtzgGVMPISFPBMh1W7x4ZRIp320eO7e2ysgXZO2B3huFN76HbHIIeFesaB6fSzZA@oyHLcIbBSJ4r/8tg@cN2AacVgWTWSwZRMazi2dTpGcnUY48Z4httxbTp0clPUWfix5@u2zgZtIt@d9x6CbPz06LAmVuYCSfrJ8Ma0cdxuebIMn/vzM3V0ljKaTvEZYfLreR67uWihJTKX0KOEHkNcSgmyYqhFU2vsGAY8U@QLDLtS3YjDKTQck5FmCZ0pKnU/CXq9BWeNOh8LyEvsmXOOOrPllQvqkNeZBcqzQLjWciHMPKACDRMvuVwZrkjDseUcQKwzjxL10OkCTAGH7hd8y9R3tgITpZ@Qg8UT9gPTjibgDsyhi5NM0EvaOJsBoj0KsmyNpAl9xQjnEiibxhkq6BJ0iHhV0IImNhJYaC6xRptNx3IknCji1iUSjhBXacMBrZvN7PmMhbqgGdPBh806mxFGzcNjSo/Exq7X2wBis16NFqytCoYpJZNxMAqV5g1i0GLSSfBrRY2XNPh0SJqjUaqcL4HQPVFloTkp7rXOk5JP0dAjfLM5uSWrH4BMgqsR129LfbNK1wOtwFc18klShh325RwNxYZ3jQFwF5KZLKIS6mfs9Fy7K7C5JKA1wrQQrKBwQj9eJRkuhjUtL1ogSVeosqjIVefWVl6De6VK69cDzK3GjAGh@EDOj7Mn56RxnCUnoj@yrQBEJJQnBuGqIufquk06n6V7nj71uXA9SI3sHLzzXkNuMQjcUMf5oRKrxUm0/Be0Ns8d44JtMOGqlsAKaK9PZ@0tLC8IORCBTiVA9gEGS6BK4oTCElHJxzyflaVngj6XMqm4NB1miZm@EHu2HgSmw2iOTdKtRjebTQmTqdHkt8Kh@QqR6fyF1YNcgh9ksUoOj@7uHRyIKNClkns4z1GB5giiIwgjqwodYXK@8BVyq5sktzBOGpVbDpoaqOvtMD4QdRWIfmzibA6ynb7ppcAxjVMUBjjTWSEakUljIYJwbZIRUBzFwFKgbG8xYJWl@X/qHDvuaVzjFaD4DMUkoDt1u4JSZlocO9YL0YfuhQqaECTUp6CXqK2nKCdbV9Lh4rMhTrCCUE0FRChBo0FAZ@LXITBPWq0qmymHsOAHbohdnqdVQVeJ15So6mvgDIIMhRBGr70izxqyUG5l1peBoguxwgXerPxzcBHCImjfXJrseoq292sNmeWBzZgx7v3Up8sfF7c5VMg6M/BsZJYGjxYXUaZD1yItrilaXLEEjQxZCR2wwIJELCERLr8PaZb6U84PWi9Gow6pNDmLka4iysn5OcUhWVcJxSGYFMIq4yLSioExPXChNA/CpffzMgFtreFyC2yzTY6vxNq8KIsyj05MTpdOrgijwgn1jTRzJgxazrFLp0NiU1sWlTwKgHHs4bF9PSau1KSPhaB0MnUWVl3iw4S3YadHH0sC0FmBcL6ZOtDx5lD0BZlRlw7oiw49L0l5cY3FQrLhGk7axYKZCC9eE1Iol2jgXqdjrQoKSMDFU9F7STDgTkjIqpgTlVkRry7DIQv4DReVhu//9nEX8Hy9FgbQE@AAXGxoQ9@MNSL0VlZKGBUt9LG8Atk48di2dIoAanodSEP3oEi6HRuWg6Zz0YIA/fsQR9bDmgUaxAdIlDeQE8s5mxiL3ssTWTa35ABPNFaFvbIsiSVFZ0FAX@tSJDApxzJpJMqbWCWYEzYTMacvI596faaitUOEEi2r98E4GLMnCLWvrURrhPdNbTAMKef1jmJKbBn3DVXu6cfjriuMjvuxIFpYEnZWejpMJEB/H86KttG4vPisgGxZdPReFWzWd0mn9PU6qvCdsT8SOlS57jIbbQjDG1LwbPZcFcQKt8HFhtVYs2z6eENKDKEDoYSLAiRceCnMIc26gmZb70xRyBh8fiqLJ9iB49SMTEbWVsywjkar46NCSeOXy8tjT0SD4WOZ6i@xxZ2hZkULHC73fE2tQrdkDXVbULtzxpVMe9n8/LWg8dQejYM7Eeh2hBuJHDseY2zr3sx0A4lfG02@Ni4ddgtPLMOFfn5ElKKoqDPmGK0Fm4HEVbT0MTffby1DWLSLQohNyxu7awS4RnIF9bwB62JrE3EF6Bw5iO4qnBjuKd4rBYIBaJnsubzverk0V2/AhgTbsHXomVcy/oXRPRw9fA1Jnlq@SR/LEXu8NKOBYS91XyT2aNxufhzudQTsW7brk0P6vAlBfQ@wwJ7LSXcel5buCHQMe958A7eJJvVnFarbfdculPqSDo@VtT72esjhw/eb8rKYFynKa3hRJOi4jhK@V3LwY8k7fl0F0b17Hi7onDPe0JkuY0jhpMXq0oGMjxsWlpfsnlyiMUWJje2tSBiXsZzq0@j9c3QSq1AbdRKjKRWQQY7DCOUSGAKPCc0/T2q5m1PrvhlTuga2@LpCzFXusW1Ct0Sf16qUqLLyOWMosvzmLKpnj82xuVR1eNz5yAw7jDdPXA6zux4OqeMoPu68iEO9DHW6N8od9rxou5Fp6Dhr93rhZJF5jUCeHqG2@wQMT9BwPUbfGY8Wam9Br3IOGGoGo6iJut2FXKDP5@UrpdfIOAuStW/S@0Zdh@lmuMKplpdlORQ95qZAFiw36UBaHPcjiz0XEqYus5RnYXHay5szLk@DomV@Dd1KlqKuUr1p4HJZcizHDKb4fEPu2HFd@/PUFDBJ3Pfqgp4p0LWiN9XYNfEl3AVBZoMLPg5JdHqrhhVY7xFqhYAfVHdvqvT5OZo3qk0BZyGHOEO0aF2eBo4Y2vqw09VJqnPqpq8DxS2ZOEjDFovaq0XBcHhCEUticVY7Xbdj2jp7TQq5m@KVRW1J2w4nP3GylE2Rzia0E1d4x2gKZbW6oB4MzKFJrTeI13oXD3cIXysDTVy8V3lPTNOQJnumsSrAyIJm7eBzYU52TnYJXAcUmwDXmaGCYONKxtB1NbIe6p7lPth59M785HoYYH@o9817kXYwNySAC2WY4jQzLh8cqJA72JQMiBaCDQVL59ic@tF7acSHUwMqajxc2egMHB18g1a2au3j9S7MGbgDZ2AO2ILj2LaKSoGQAgo4pB6nP8C1TqPRwhroeTzYrm3P4wFZDGM4rttbmsYe7oXELTxL47MN1uHrtcNUesAaHxpWkunAHAMf993AHZkCta0KauOQBnuu4jnRVO3PO1Zyo0YLqIjePy/81@pWfd0NRiP6ao/ssU8fNKpAt6q@Tp7osbUVdBWc6/XFl@6wI4aOYrjwgs7mLm/THSswBrhXmFGk2Xc7xsB6XabD8wmkaHCDWd9Id0PMWES4i86g0AN6vamI9FKb9z/E1/6qSg/HSVhnEBtu6N@XjUXR3bjCSD82fDbuhyZSwaHPudbF9uxW6K7nyouxFcyAzi3GiQcy2UA7GlblPVxDsFISoYviZ@wwXFuwkkqp8IqCqmDKICAoq5JdXJ4118Q0jT2W8gbDNY57EXteiclwXQod4rLmBh/BfYF0FhbULJWsncG471/nbWzMuQvSCj5Wa@R0XercuCt0C7oTvlZhULUl3LAG7zaIH2PzxomB/I0zAzScYgu6a8GrDS@olfHK4SHbGvnsSYTeynmjcJ0NqJlXJ7cYbqbL9cSwYrpmj43jo@l1Mhno1yC89qE/Fwyc78VhYOTTrNNmPMlx@8CvBZvMAkdhV@lKS9fBLK/@uHsTPnhk9nVcFPvACnD54BKqoO1j2fqZ18L@4lj3rS@OoWSriA334LM5M29@9STalsB7qPct4/5CRcSZDBEcrj1krwXyR6frdXE6sHxcdxMbbhhzQZJjRIxU1wYReknIq4PP8fEDswbEtrQtDb1sgNgdTXHnz5SabhobtgI6gBi@V2lRq1Y53ZiJ0/FwNPbD1/I80JU98wOsQ8bO/FMLgAsvgGuSgW4Hywdh50YTQZAK@7uZcXmSFfKhZbt98mFJJiB3BcRCOXcJ4dyBnvcJLhvxnCWUSNN@w7k71PkFJrf5L6BuTVyg7ljBzQMYQYBLSKI3FoZ1Cu4pyAMP8Cluf14IwtFyjDyY6@Ti7aSv6aKBwg7dsWeYaIzPiJiXyEPo5m60AtbCXfV4xsXpvGZjuDY0IzDYS5uG4TrjQPDGzo3cv3Aj96/gOUFz1U1SX9x7@DQ9X@t0nfDrBMnoJKmZaeXs9hVishyQpVbzy8XQkdh/l51wc0CXq74mzg4ew2NQtnzXXaaCPJlCR7GMmY@Hd00D57Jem8Yj96HruNC7jIDxDQ9Mth97YZXB8ogY7QHuOAY8dF@bzCEFu6JTYdKDPjI7UI/2zPQmfQsDfFcP9BVdCx32oipZbHotTVh2x/Q@ouNZc@ZVWuNihu6bE6oGrCYM1taEwDCY9IpDTQttYWFywR@5rsOelHvK8FIe3swlgLXTx5vP3oq46HtB9V6qSi0W9fEJW7pgdtmBAavK6pkd12bPGxbEOBabqNY9y/SlB7j/nLoVckQAacq/kVcUb@QVMy0GJNMT3aczx8u1ghlIZfI51qUMdM9wcdImNNywZGRu0/hr2HG8jpzNZncA8RPgTLoxDo94fF227GFnSB8rFYC52jwwIZkuLlg7nDqBPrlemWzwJdxmPrfMKN6cHbElbNQFknoC2kV6uQJ3BXvWiD4o5105g0tXigiOZRovdRxocileZsOrC/5QNukRNa4Ybp1rLnQgVNLpbuOlLWZx3RQIIrYpBAMP1HApuGmENjrqYsmQ/nho4rzn4kTCSpHT9Qe0sO7yKd6YiXqmEJ66BjwjPoGNyXXCzkqJEcHD//GddyXoVNuFXHT8A7Co108qQ@bHnhO@3oTSnrh@0LMmjyHfuMZ8FdvAYuUhCrxYC0DTxqpCQO05Y5sNCPTnFv0Mu1SNEugZuoJgU7YcmILpnAj0MK7J9RK5bPuQtINnqwZmVwj3ouNgufAg2kkUBwvfS@b05nkgrihUJIbYSSEXrjFchtzTiAOA/OQGwsinb2nkP9l/8PhIHPnK0n5oZ4Br76/JZQub29WSPDdK9JHuzU3NsbVQXcsPpDuHirD7YF/EACvwzUbvBXjh5NLCa@VQZHSepqSv1F7Q1wyWC3z3jx4@yMw23pHU7sBzh2Z63nv38DCL@xjePVzqPR/7HrSOnjtZGX1/T1HSS8g33J25iksuSWkVpCMTtEggxvvsbIzXClGGOzK7R9OR@R50ksip/TdMvrCykI/0E6uPrZCUVyKKNlRSFgu59NzyX1CSTS9@r6rPY2uE3NKgL4m9Vq6QQAlBkzxtuZRw0@T0VWmFyOHk@OeLpMjXqXX@RFdJ9/@pGVMUZRWeD/Ue1CvJr6ysxQDLpjht9@QNZkPNUBkRYichAKoSrNcuVi4KQ2DdEj5wxDx0BGNn5cqMmwDEzoWlDf7UdKa6I6C0FLqM3FjK@NCcm6uJF4uc4HHPS6et4vXWJGVQY4TmI2/Oa3f3zn7kccDcQ9s7j56SJ7oPGs8SiOYcxJlk8ZGA4zV4iteqgYv9rgecmvUT/dFyuq@QQ93rus50MtdUcBYXuzp6cGUcB200kGlbE2sZ7zbY@MyT5StBojTYCnl3uiDnzR@MEUa4/PKvK4os02NP8K3IzHqFgEkKTfoUz8ya9zraj0nfwH5ZBIf0Uq3qgTnBFQNslHKZcrqUfxdu4O3F9Gp2eZNf6Qa/3A3pXfNDR9xTodwAMH@DH8mLsfcD1z4duOKu7pk3oOOmrJdvyHp5jt@EJzHT2avQvFpoxZXg4WspvR2ZgZcbDdyOlVsQkRc3UK4cbg90j64/6Lvh4nlmX57U6ThqyA/1l@Z8Ez6e8QFzMMYl40sm0jogiJlO32IHr5E7brBHbTdoC/H@0OVzzdbo7nh0hZXgGfVXuNP7oJS5pz65gzt@ZvLhEuUS1xYtd18lTJF4hAnPGLx/tBMl@vhQUudSnOXigycLzrgnLnh8OOfmmZPJKm1LmKxSXpb6zFJ9dJRbSHaz/uzkNfsqoGcDVhe/V3a5jO@8e3i9daKmMAiGduTzru6YEZyuG9BNUvE43GQ0Gxx9f0AJIOJjSxZ0QS9iWQDDl9ptPLSk3V5FJUfmB3RgGfpKEpgTFOuZgB@eDWROcoMg/GwHjbKyAbjHMdc@HA0sZxJahjN3XOtGUh/5UYl3yKHtnpJI4ZlrPmGPBVH0E9O5eVOTUNZu7pC1@V53AU/s8P/wtQpFd1b03ndMz1sW5sCQ7kWW99T0khDvHkYBlvnu2i4Oknat8XCZN42aySzz8hYa9tVI1jIPPLv@eOB6zjLPqGIqlTvmStBrN/gNp6CtLfPo9HrLnPd8d5nzw7EdWCikRZ6P3DG0nois9rxIeqtv1ptNsSLOrHgUrz/w0vMuwCmG7tgH8c6y01eDCh9ZwYLjFXxTNzwL2HREx70K912XfMGa5XO@EC9XYundezOfxXHiMc4U0t1xM@OqnVKjqfZa8n1p9allOeE51vCK7@yYpX3PdZgtPT/vEx2ytATafd220qsnQtXXzIQim2P@5ERb1sqA4d@bx@h700ksOT@x6Zbd0LarQgH6hpEOPxXh09WXijY3KMCWjKxY9jZj2V/cG@rG/JDjwlkL0bSRP2Pic5qFd/jozs7R@08ehPYv6MNOlEJ0PLp6l63aitdoXBlGoQfIS4f4FPyBDn0XHUERcPf0lRm093cePInY8QBEckAlnvE2N9AU812S6nq@PizHEuTDaJ/SXWh7aJ5xovtT0xXGcaFYf7dMzV@5e@DqGVE3h5472elabTwyg8Ox10uv3MiqLld2Dh@sYqvvRsU8fOfhu1@8N9vm9MgaEllU4X@lZYiKKF91Uq87adedcted8tedCqJ8ReZbIQ2Ky7XSGFD5OmzlWt7V6xlVr2dUvZ5RNc7onJN83WlJiiG22N5xkBDmT@f3s@EpUeysBbbD3RejTyikUg4w5vTil6zmt@vjGdapdTzDdZ1uzYew5@dkLdwODx58tME@PAAAj3q0nLGJO/jZt2yC2jokU6sp@TLZws9EVYgi0zTx23pldqJelFiDrJ@Fm9srFeWCrNUIX@FJeLxAfEA2O@QZAOPxtFAoIhwrZD0An/VoazyhXy0h54SOuQoGngIKNlGaPySkGh4eAHlaP3uy/2Tv8Gjn6OlhQ25dhIcLRKVwHEgtOsLkltblofAh3kDXZUe@00MtbEiOfqoCx2r9qFwEv9K0WLTaQtFmheK3MM76meNIEj1fQRIuIH8Cz1KjvihsghODHZWYVlB4tEaFHXVAT2yAOmKgeZomVFqFyMsSHum@D8UK/a9@6Iz64ofyKvipPEw4PKUbZNu@63bDFH2TvP6KUry3s//g6cEeiTI4o5pTqxsMauU8O8Q9PL@Nx9MWbHoQSTKMkoS6qtWS95KAmKSYJBV6IgY9QB3PekvG9IBnaYSxN0hqncIHDCbjSpH@28fSRVLEDRppCJuMMpWEZIHmKaHgaXdHQCTk7sH@e3sHBPO/d5c6I4oQBDnC3fp/@YMu@wRJdEhW9JFAbxjqclBbvmt1K3hGhmGSRE5Rw4N2ugQPiGPHSBBzQj/nQSmPDiTNfTYwTQ8u4uYP9ohOu5gdyIE1RznAfEz2qRB60EX8jZL4U0scRw/iA3o/pedIXjliMU2PMWOfRGSHn8agKelFnzvAiVbQPan8YfkWHrOB9dBzx96VRoJb3@mJoiLZwe8n4lcadfo1Hcjs2AnYiWzhKU0JoFAx5lVZsk4zy769w88FTG6uQSPpmH3LIb5jgbgZVMhHQME4yVlhx7AIQj15LUoEukJNAiqYcwGZMjzEM@2JMNrDo/WannT5a78i9asEzAGYvxqaJ/IdsH0ttPXA/HVmfiYhgUrJa59cifMynyE8cjUsAcsI17N@9jP8pCqfWleU47Z3kknm5So8lGqe5Mmt9aYgrDfk2va6DogMXkya0JyljdyJeXfQ6@73pSbPg0yak6SNs7Oz5L2NJ9azPCkIXUstvJhML7SC9mJyoSmlF8cjpdAQX0xafKmWPW41Gy3y5MkHr9qv0vzkhA5FpoDAdh/zSo5PVMrkbKugJY7L@Lk1KOExeQnXcY/gn5pfdufMOpo7PaDbJE8SzSZ@/5Qv8sD2ki34U07xHC7GMxp1sS5utV69Sjd0PZhMiWVZI7/bhdsdkJSqpg8JNLXb0IhYBIk06ZsiEa78cNIjkx2z3x/v6VNrfC/YFotiSVTnGNPmww/fD6/q@0@fEvKUPH368mAFG2tlMilBaFDzJHJ8AGJidkIqbT2fwA@m/eVnaxfZsyftzb/8ZCiZa/h6jK@vXjxE86GSv7W2duvOnVwuq6oqMz/58Mkv7uzs5O5m808a@a2cIK9t/sWfr62p6qYqrbV8X2klG8fHH/CqnOPFv/x@sv3kyRd9v679149f1RV8FOFxQoqkjJdGFDDiswS3QvJ58qZX4mVCgSsxpb92InI/WyNKfav437/5@EUiSNRV6X0P3kHiRaJQSjAjGMCmRbaTRD2xicEKF4mpVKvVwFj87/8e4tffBTjoM92ERz0fwSpME3WhRqOcJ@oFMCiqCun@3x9/PJdD4GfASmrQIoVS5LYNDLHR4HNFld9qwbVBr00OTycSZEmKwjnBIDBdopRuK7fRYoEFXg68cCypmcBPRj7eJuKzgwz0CRnxvfqadHdTgEscSYqiNhXlNrBf4dZGrSZAv0Kbrablb@PJkWnaG/bdwCXm7fcXrsT7/69cS8FU3//nuQ7IrmWYnpvlEoW17ed363UouVbXNuoZeoXNjba8Yol33W3gOkeDsWe5@BXK6gP8nkqdl0sqn81mtw/aEIVMJohMYTIR2wiCsG9cJ9gltglzwYYdOjKqhKuOPKFFYncWK7LOwpHnyQa0ltbz1eESe3j91X/8q2//1Tfp79v0/s94yJPTtXrSBgQ6gYZTh2u7UjHqdb7u8WdNtNeB2uRKqVKS2hfN1Eaj3joAAfed82ReS5JDe5qFQqgqaaabDRq/TpOth8mjvZ6YOdeZS33eLfRggakDvENMkURUzrlyxVgj5Eo4LhEtTBIaJ/WWgGObNaGhFPItgcVqbEPl8GqxzLdbCWF9CjxJbdXVvPqYbNfZRQbrPnExN5paiAoS5rc@K9vMZ2arzzsl6lG0@izM5w0X5qkMJfOlUPasRxndXquslSqFiiq166uv6iwGXjSoaZpP/MRJIr6qJKTDCJ@JmDLn3J7N10RcLSQiYLIQ9zXhuESj1miZLWgj4X/ZRatLKyh8NTSpbZ5UgT5UTVD7bV5WoLVttyN2vgXXGvzoH67Yis816hI60yDXrzVSUTZUTcrfKuyp2AdfvYgnNOoZyiOFVj0jIq8UxCuBOOhViNHpdF4aHZBRdL2jG7oS6GN9ok/1oDPuTDqBMTbw48LkCQp67RAHnubm3ZIboUQUElpeWU/cRgrX1DJ@pxe0lFJJK6taUdGKBa0oq6W8ViprxZxWLAJArahq5XJOVbVCUSuUtEJBK5TxW8gQpgBhNIRQzGtljUu8aqyRA8bfJiQTXc3Ma6@nIuVoeFGDi7cguJMEiFBj4zjLJf4ZrrqiKmQDukkZHiAbUiNR6Q9KuKtbYz/LkQSIfWetVxuNVxtkvraEMM/wEtvbrYxwcdEAc7Ua/jfrsbFKL2aCorYuMpnNZ3WQhp7VGxkA@SwEKQqEAhXbddLapF5xamFyof9mq9UH38zI7yPJCDQTLyATmc3GZs3dpbdIW6fQglQ2F3K@vU1JbRti1dehW0hnMuuCsNYA0I2wg4LASJBhEQESBEuBKHN29nPeZHMTmMzF5kX9orF5cbG5Cf9N@rwI3@B6sRn9kzk3WXC3Yzt9za75oHNhZv4t5FPNhlRvSs2QV7XALkp1dBGlJhjq8IZwDU0ttbB3RDlIbP3L/IvZ2TN2wSy3RMg1l9ggGwk8F0lLbHCJ55ef/q94Ny8//SHKtAR@ZoVLnBHCJaSNMqFu9FUGwe6hQx6yywEz3pEVXdCh/hAdHfZwUFOWpOciqQhUXU4ppUJaxO6/7fbauPFUJM8hKATb65vQiCLeS3i1VODbGWWqksQmXyhSdvsL165kMvmvnqvlYpJp47hz8rnv@w/ncjnLJwSuqrIiKOd1ds4tO4j8F5Zd/@oXVl1c4rxMEEcpwvDCJYCMEpIEWiSXqG8OcRkffsRDwK@xndQ@EJ7uCLvucKQHVF3HsTwQFWr7e7VyuY5qlLn@hDaejbsb8FTgv7cGhSDNHgRt9mrGEET0Zk/Lq03UWt/RQXsHRid0XuDvwUv8kSMDfwcv8EeOXuLvIMAfedjB39EL/O108Hc0xN@dF/h7@BJ/T/v4a76laUqVX9dPupMu/Ccv1yfrZxRXGaWsXKxPeIazxFa9@Rag009WyXbyrQYdFcqXWw30bYHHW4E3rYSfp/CnfhZXWZoGYtw0Ury6pfLpKqsyYBZarpx@iw3JVMhbRK@Vq52aWg2jx1FrjhvbRMuPPhKYYttyK2oaB0K0ct71BJ1YPjzAIaOVFddL/vQbn3ySrNWSQpIe6J4DN6GDgTo0EFghZq5q1ZS3QJl5JZgVlruUmX6LDr9V3iIEy/QWjl66XmqYtpxkl202kcZjqytZroSfw7X6Ix1XBkos@3hem@4xN@nEdE4k0xkPpZfWSB@NJN80PDPAQ9yAJibBCYSaxRORkrp6oEsvXcfEYS4pcIc2QkyyM4lTvMSnK@02i9JuQ66qVgbLEI5wsVKkrM08lDJlm07KM0deSlTS6bpGjzoVhJyWg9Ln03hccT0fOSplsCvpt6DyiGiyL10lgCgVLlEj68q6ItuyISsdpQMGi8gekQfyQOmCItxWiGwSeSpPiTx0lS6YTPjJYLLkHpH7RHZkBwKCL5iCthygqQevPvx6AMiDn4VrqzqKbBBIyEZ1mX5jCsGD6bxN3hm4fpAdNbkGSRL@ufn8@XMcyBcLVgu/ONDgnz9vShsttVwiIjIGsd143ky2@CaP59Gq5RzpTM215nMexDuZZ/WNLgTK2Ui2qgmp2ZRCKlVzlPAvLtrtvUd3220J5YwmMeuZ7Qx0ktvbNeg0w9dWol7dalZoNxx1xQlpc6tZ1wQ0FzLQo6rgRu6bUCVZKfM5rxlgeNfXKAJaz0@fgzaZOkWd8vQEXqeR4f0mPNpM26Te0un7zTkrNcCFYSXp/SUQFgyQa8ebxpIj/EE5/@f6W/@y/g@fknSq0Uqnzi42U/RKp0iapNLp9NnF2UX4rKdTqdCS2oQfOoAdI51d1NFIA52BqZFKt9IXF8wNnqk0BMcfRNms06izYGckwZIMf@GDWggYSGrmwnKVSs2HmQWBUkAIFg3nqxZDxQ7pVHg1gc8/5zc3PeO8WaXMPieXSYJ/XtVnEzjN5kSW08C6wwOzBYes6@d0tDtdNfBrdOudhtL6i@/TQ9G30jRQPletKhuEWdScWq3mIluxVK2WIst6KlW@ftXlLaUAimgul05Xq2DZisDKYIW4DfIqQ2qkCc/W7dsskZJ6fh7B1HKFjIwTZ9VqlFIekjV93aANHvTTs/3H9EBx4Bj5BEHGEA79p2T6QYIT3U4l@Qp/@3Yq/OTs1k769m21LJ@fxy6jETgpC07tdtfy2m10187P@TZP51zKebDLpfNzRS5nlCQBtpx6hN8NRQYuKOSWWqfJIntWc0XwTjYnSkHBzk2nnVuhhOf5I5vnmw6fXqvxyWbTSfLol9PK9KPLHnBzaseOEJ6IANZ3V8n/oCvJJ6t84oxiVikVGXvlq@iMSidwGnJ2kaC0RXL5dAo4cxr0g4sE/jxk4rRr0/L5dDUny4mzC54FVsplFjpNcoVUKVMOf7W1NKmD8Mt@KMFrmdxGcWMbhzJ9ek2uX8jnq2dmTbmonZkV/EDORdUIPxSJe6/N27e1MtRWSU6Qu2M8ASLb5MJOogaCEMrR8GhyyWSG3LrN4cZ0L1mpblNaU0p5kkhWmaOQhM6GlKDaJXUjr5QQJZzVwxMVQBjkFIq2NbLGqfSND67MkLmGjgkuEbPk1/25LlykSzqkjxfp45gDsYhNL2IT5k@fhhEHctkV@sZWGpeOUkQuZnyxORctr7H2lCQPxoaFo51PHuzs7h1l1U2BJNR7O7tZ9fDpnYSC1vzMTr01tB/s7dx9/BQiPHmwt3O4987@e3tPn4C7T05nV9ynRT1b3MPNmZbYT8n73EfeS900dXNsmu3T8fj0BfnIstoWVLk9hrK5fY/4ZhuKNNJnxavCbVi@/tFHujeiF7n83pcvv/dLl7//jcvf//Ll73/7p59@@8tw/wDub7D3N/64nMfnTz/99T@8/L3fB8f/DPefwf3ZTz/97Y/ZTe0/gvu/zLn9KLznwrGbA1hf@@mn3/z@Tz/9@nfg/t3w/s71@9c@W35/@0urb4z3zT@8Ocw3/j3cf8RgRWG/8XvMDd/Xwv8eC/f171z@5n9g/78If2j8/cvf/BE@Qsuvfucv/svlJ/9JVUt/8W8vv/TNyy99cvmlr15@6V@rl7/9bxV5/vGHl9/@k7/50z/6mz/9N/T/A/r8ozf5X37nV//6f/vr//2v/zS8P4P7P4Dps7/@T9CM//5Pvof/b/7J3//Z9/D/v/zB3//Jt/7@a/8zNfwOM/zj7/4xe/74ky//@Eu/8eNPPl3x/PKNz0/fwP3TfwaXN8/nm8B5k3J9XpdPf678/FOwMUsFaAAo95cvf/srQLy/CX3U5Zd/gBtB4F7x/4Gq0DA/YLb/DxjU62VGHxlMcH/r8svfIB8glv4nwBL8yQcfQO/0Qdjlf/DBByEGv4p@4P4BdWTXYkTmGfnOfL5KZuGgGr5LSOP58xbOZy@Appaffvob36e2hFmp07lK7PVLaimzAWrbRrkcT2JuYvivxCATi9HzJc1xnGqY7FeRdS2k8FVkepff@/jy@//68nu/c/m9r2GnL@TK2Z2soLxmIhgC5t8gHAYsvEk4DAjJtzN0BFfIgNk8l3B70vY5IVUoh1bSmrPgptTrbVTgR@BRqWycZYWtJsiQtMQXNC7ubwJxVBHUW5mtNYkoelbb0HQIKOVYOFJxtuVcprih6xLXPpdwLxQ5J3NGSWEhJTXEJfPCtWNSCFlS1NhrPQIQF4NLZDC7GSoGbUTCWV4jk0xYkkm4WADdIdBkgxonhE3xTKj3hJvQNQXRf2accCRDJSN64WevIiM1hPGi9QhFuMOC5CGtzGwWiYqMhElrG8yFLrWgiedAZ6Kzs5lJrY4GnP0Arzugo9RqGYxYY5kCK8tfvURofjKZGhQeY7M42XYJQUzuUCgQs0bxUJuwiBmEV49wkuHQieYmU6rdhQRrk7vokEHgFOzz57V6qTapI7hXDCmZSeYOzRMCq2Um9Vdgr1GYEI9L3H0FWSnVMpl6CRPEQrI6wrlZrKk8LRwtO87zs4qANy6229om5BavlHg2h7aGCGOh8ZmZhcaAGOXgOa@o/HM@p8o8BG5mNsKy0X9kpPcGxf4aTTdMkpUdU16jwEj7@cbzMCANCakJgiiKBG5c2LJFtskWx7CWydDMwCsTIpESCyWO2IFQTHEZWusMbQAfnOnHQYmq5qqglFQJOnkGh98So6ulZG59givhzkgoKMvhBzIvOB3C5GSNOzvXw5Vy6zq5AKcChyFomrWNz31hZhFr6@vrXKLOa/xjuiIgI0nEO67Q9Y7Q9qh6VSF8ocyjs0kXfzIsPsRND1mOmqtYTHL58fcTObmY4NaT9GPEhCVEbmXYvb29QW4BWul7zm1ClxUKGc3NuQmGxs1Mhlch0boLtg2KwgyFxj0jiRr@wT1ByQ264Ce6Z/lZLksZXxZeYi2B3uTx48dhfqnDsxqXgXaoagracTZ4PB5DdLOLKy@yWVHMitls@BbpmzqIoUGkvuFbXEfUk3k1UCmW8CukjjFAvHCvXr0C2uAQF5V9HOSmRlJTcyXqSSgZTHDBnz7McuxwBtueRuuK1VyZY8MqRCnkCElRioArTXABbQpoPM2xVXiMvKIrlVRLpSQNCTUmpiAYA1NQkFOxlcp0GxbJFxeskLN5Kw6YsokNXBISLxFm@UuV8unIc/cx2X388OHeo6NRq9aC3oZ@9tZsjzzXMH0/hZ47j@4y@lXLhTTOv2Ppjyoq8k5uryIjIWf27x7sH1YIw1lYeSlakipdTxFipqxwidHo/c2Eh9Mrnsnj155c/hCflRkyUmpZg6iJOpcwTNTKgFLxD3eVHJh9JOCHfv@OOyEpOcvzWaWAunQaFzxAdn7RHRM8zZEdIQH8AddzilBizHn9TJibYESHOjlQOWYQFGogWrkUGYrMoBQLGOAx@x6axtUP944A8tFjoqiySA7cjgWZqn9AJiIhwAUO3KHpZoULGht50pE1dDGEXbNNpx8M1vEbs3xT5ucQtN6Qs/hTNQ2eSq6QVfLF1tqafSYgnCYlmjNcrXoB1jMBcfI2XIR7myNvgxNcwgXh3JHpkHAGZv9xlZEvbk4mKcj9YeDxSh44Q5rDKakQHjeav6qIdWhqi5O7XGLtww8DUq/vPbor7N/DIYvJgERrXQWrKw5ESjrdsWdS3z4hXes9CzdOiF3LH9n6FNoxIGyjDhgJcOY9cXFx0QOY@/eIWleplcXt4vPCoC4dMF9MdI4Aj@5xidvRKA1XvF2p1F4puSLkrVJ5pakqBw7chsQlrN4akBtdrbQhsR/v1HKKnFHYxEDKIWme56s@ZErTStIGl1B4Hl6apnG0DRGuYnKErmZ7JddqQsjmcwpdzMbhGff6pKbGVxh2cmsWVpNZWPQBD9IPPCJHfkXmF9qingGKgsu76ddOo/FK@fZtDceqtJwcl51Q1JALqNN1LafRSrpnOgHSGUHfViJXDKdLoZytBGebAenWwJxoYsFpumy5PH5x3idjCFnIAVM8ragKmzrLqbkETzA0skqtJHOJRgJ4ANdoAS/4H/5rNbjW5F/uH9DSaNS4CfDS@Tt0xjD0HV4c99B9PPs/fjyct974Hz52Hz52hy78obd8iEy@OvtXqwvWm/8hb0X2Wq1CVnEyE0hUBlklD9Z//PbH//Cb//EffuurIl6hLXb4x29/i7n/7q/j81vf/odv/dI/fOu3qMuv/cPv/pvQ6x9/9w/IXWAC05c60ubl1z@5/PSPL3/42eUn37384Z@idf7/6b8LvT751swRzOhy5f8t8re/9n/83Xe/@jefffx33/rs737nT3788dfVkvLjj3/l737ns7/5s68RsP/kR1/58cdf@9tf@eTHH/8yhJv//@RHX428vhQ7ghlcrv/BHeBy//9144UMGtef0CUVm@Ghn3W6O6KhlHOtPeBxDdLajM4DrUPoTbbfkeCBLjUeCVAKLObG133T7om456DGb47qmqzym@Gh4nXynulgHxLGr3drXdegXwavdkULv9COO/tYvFyOr7oOHv1Xi1YfgKSRPuvXTumO/apZ64t4yIzn6DZE77jdqegHUxASDdd2vVoSVN4kyNnvWa5NqRjMO13XQRnWqZmgZuEMw5am5SpQPnHkjrbUfFEgQkORQfDEWyllu9APelvQ/1bU7Jq5VSxWuqJhm7q3la/k0duIV5ts5eVKX/zg4YP7QTA6AInJ9IOtXBki4EFteKTSVqmSzwNL4flMg6bYwk8eMwFDWFuD/tjUuwK8cTGKL6ilVoWmX6slk1uaogpKRZNLXFjYGcKcqiPklMKWXAnm0Uj2bMtxvSzP4ZdZ41rAChwo9Zyc25TgTaDucWUMiFN1smP2TeyPaM0pm9IIaQKMEFQHYweM@U2pA0YLjOVNyQLjuK4p8qY0BqNRzyngajAqwdogVrcGaWLJMpjtLJJLdqCchfJFxXEd84KrZPWsdUZrrtLr9S42zjIzC0ls09Xw6pXV8Gegt50JLBzU9oWgZztnsbUqzCBwFTLOCtbME1z0HhDPWbhEqMKr@RJfbVRn9mKBr7YuuO2h2bV0/N52Uz67HqsAIiGDmoCEmoS7qHiuG1Q6Zs/1zFlATSlEAVmGrgfI8Rdxck0ZUzy7nlxhLtDkbIbXGJ8d2zWOw5To9yeXpZXL8xecEaLDM7sXLKFsJRs5sqiUbLAasUITz55xiY2D97R6Hej2LFdUc/lcXtUKhXxRBfG3nCvkS0A2ckHOqyowj1y5VC5eQKuVpFcJ@gE7snsWteYK/YRBSq@wgz0bLZJ@9ciyz0qawNhPKl0FcSnxikvcOnhPrddXj8OlQJV4TxXqNS1fBpOGJlWjQpWqCqomaIqgaPh/jUHF/5uHV@Gv4hNiaSp3hMcePQIpHhQYhzzAk1sClxy5Lt33dsc0VoTYHej0iKVdz/X9f0KYO7pzzLzuWuyM3djrvo4fevOHVjBYEeLpaGg5Pm6e@@eCsDfsQAaR27MAd@Dh2a67LECRPH0Cj4P9d@4fxe/lpX4Yn1oPyGHH1kOMo72d3ftcgdx5/OjulVc@BJcnD/buHcXWIvONouZjEL@49@DBVWv4yj1@etAbux7e3L3HT3OzR@yE2wW5HFyLgWJnCiR8oBVFPFRVyBrJFyODwuFOxdu5MrkdGvOFmVFG4/tsL6Tlx5sZ2XbaCncUbZDUCXYBHZPgh7HMLh2ipYc4hiMbSrHMcSPiuKekKJOua9s6foC@twaOA90nHdNENd22kRIx6VPXs7unVtdcA9EY0igr@LFvzAR3H4AMx8YAEwAtCY/@7eKn4XF9Rccem2Q8Iisd4YVOaPSs/gAkjVM3CsB1dJ3A/XkviG/OX8HNDgFLg7pd87GvB@cS3M5jHIBJlHh@l@fv68VnBIWnQbaU1SoOH@T5Pk5s237QbWyMQcFbW9vKlYjalHdlukxtqkuKVO3UiFI4r7vbOKaw0Tb7tYqfLyhb2CXX5Mx2wvXvm6VSledHvu5kgVVmKz6OpzjWM2JUnQpo@KMR8YsbhDTNc9Qhd71mc5KrJpPYW1ACq/ztd3/wkz//1uVXPrv84W@hDEjuup6h48p6VMYJVa1DnVykY0FquZQvlTW1lC2VS7m8Usjns4qaVYqlYhkyKislpVDKl5VsKVcG4S1XBt98uRhq9JK0QXZsHMTLMq1d2qgAeMfAb19v0mElcVDnEmzBDnmZ0tMkocf2MeFNiMOTHadv2gADxwMDukF3w6pB100UmWhFApB1YpDEvXu78r17PH8HLbiScVfm@S5a8iVZLt7heZP67JZQPuVdFqeEBzryAbPI8h2oxTEDgN8w4PkBWvYKOEnD8xZadnfu3cN0emhRMT4EO2Y@zGJHliIEc9CiaQzAixgaBNth6eRoRvfQgkmizz3mswt@PP9OlB30OWDBGID7UUl3dnh@n1l2dtBnlxY7zzL6BbTs0IvnPbBAE@P5Phj6HjRunu@AERsazxtgMqY6uOH3xvH4eyfQeX7K0IMI4vkJDa0bxzzfjtwxmffC3OQRuxVqUVipt6mljD@eV6NMYzAttmg8n4stOSjb/fvv6YOga/bZNfXY24CS3r@v6dZkvHev8847nX6/40139t45QK/d3fsg1EzHXqffCSN22nC5EGv3vqofD6dXLyj1frtd0e2lXl9ot3O6c8WrPW2bmEOI9QJyFl59TGjY3gWv3fvtbX3JYqcJBdhGHjOEdwevO0N439E7zCu6qBd9TzodvgrNAFSZZopD7QsXLGHzPAae7WSHuuG5VbRPakSmC/ynjYLcqlIPMgT1Sa5eoH8vhU8dx9zTZ9PGpCa3apNaUWUjbb0U35yoeYvPrg23lHK@sqZvKWouM6ng2QJuL0mSgrJFUsrtjZck9Si9pYIStcY3t7YEvqG0tgrFZ8jgKvjYUpVSJSerJM2sWrECceSkTAg@0o1ia6uYr8wiF4sZXVIrxSKIf4CfAISIDg5yt0kqdWrqx@k0Zp0OkkJ5aMHJlBbaqvZSk@ykxjJJpunqpKZU2ZnRRL4CLZXq4ocIxgYeWEMY0D4AnIAWhQvlUrxSLvGQB0nCZZo4dMeQc5aTSxdnZ/7ZWfMiZpUSmGbD1O9/8ej46OgD4FYglUzZ6F49HOB94pnI86IV9@/c3xX3H0c2/MaAeA8FZNcTd5HHLfgwSTlyOgJFSrwPXTso0ZEbxAk81xb36JJ0kLIjj@igHzE8B1g8ur8A53DgnrKUIZJfRUFOx1Md8BMMVpfotTqY9C5J0VwRPX1KhYp2vV5r14bmcBRMoYhRrC8Q@n2CGZh9n@WdfhKmb3qERj/ree4w9GjX5Avo@yaJiSCQHZDxxl4WILZrRFCeD93uczVjVHGFPrlTu4Ngqm14d6pmzfQ81@NBi@WrvS2nNnZ8vWc@MT08qmL/8ToIO3jSS6pHzPQ6ae5h6F3UrS6EukecWR4fjYcpXah30otOOCkSOyCaUl@Min@GkwKQc56/qPZqJPUMgr4Au7dOUl3xTnorVwWM3SHtNDjJz3vPe0QlhVyVqkIphAVNkGIKMaCna/UvgIzGQB@TSgVyE1b5MUDFxAAw1Ab10dMj66Jq1GySEsgkTXGUq/ZrDYx@jo9NAYQMQWict3BO433UD16MofOsQ3OvThN6zR936Fd5iNxRVLlQnYCbUsxVB1Df@rNJ1auNxp5ZtcEazoIQWmK9CrgFFAKYl@epy698nN4U8jXmVqWgqNjRFtu1SdXB81SBUmpaDTwyjZyczZdAtskXsyBCqIWsUshq2VxWKKIryA/ZfBYcQRUDASllp3hC@Kw8kUUlq5hKNiU/t7rP09njlAx4oMhLZwN3zxkPCbpAlSG1Uju89XRG3QAUdV2ibwqUeIHJVLFcgPsBGVnZAYV0YOo2i5AWiLaRstdTGGj9aDzaa7Qqlb3J6IvglRJebBUyRTnzMp2uptbSNd98QWeM7lhAIDogFzkTLf5oDWg6nCki/njYgFoHk1JUK41GB8talLOarEExrfZ5f5Ov862svFZQoM4u6ISAQhhnmZ8bAcmJm7mN2qgr2CbUoVJWqxzdPpIgd7wxnazRSqpQlvIbeZlNkDAQ3ChkkYhbkmpG@4OSqWSyqCaTM8U6naziZPQaP5sbpOo2XUqcSgLLJsnbar6wxYMAyFf4sspDsBnHxVwSOcr5BtnVTV/3cBKJw@EKkgN1/Yy7OLvYrHMTkdsbWralZ0GSNfDzdpZxLHL3XK@bJR2rT3p6gG1Z5HagtPsVkTsEXc@kpsYefuKAsPj0kBaM1goBVugMWzCYgvjrQfwpnXAMxOuuUEsE31FSiyHIW9whnvGxqT7DX/HZw53H@Lu3ncBtKWT7LfArg3vp2cOnj58@vkfPcZhtr/481zZHJLr3ZCK2q4kqHffH1RmQDBat8jlWf2/jHDyR1vCAApIRBbFOD8HYZqk0w@OYpDVCPu/mmMxm/Rl7N3GDKoDm6PnqDdKiy8NNC1V18p4OAuUWSUKV696woapaq6EWQSyBrqshs6CqqlQhF@0E3W1dB/qenEGmNzN1POriC2Q61TNCVPTbpN7PrMvqNHHS5gtljZ7G0K4r8jFZS97ewA@HCyRxcrxWVzcyyScVLZO8m9RyiZNUc72eUaZJiWxk1GkPF6fhiigpCeFUc@OWtpF8mqmU@tmKksGnCs9Kkghrie12djtd9jlKySSxgOC18k5tp3@wE63n39mtl9RpeERH4lmbLxXDLDbXAWVq5tn2Qvw6yELPcPb2Sr39PEv9t3H1e7KaTJwlSSJ5kbxoJFsAutGIT3yptWbZx7V84doHLVcg6QRJh7ZiOeGn4oUHbyW3E0mc3Se@/woImtYDbdbRYQxfeK4Ck0k4buTgjgMc6QUxKp/HueuE9Hzkf6iWtIf7j5273j2TSzTXztdcXJdAqjwDyZNXzrtfBAUWaitJmrXEpJYLJ3@Vel1QNlU8gK1IKiAA9JSCIJ/XGSerU4@CCj6XX/lObrJZArsqK2BX1XxGrdeVDRBBE6PLT38YeFNytvfezgOSxKnkn/z599XiT/78D@ia@eQFnV5WtWICQqJRKRQTZ2ejszMQAC@YXz7RSlxbCtgCNEmKXi5uiNUKkUql8obYlhLhxsuUUlTSCV9IhDspCnkhlVIkNb2hleQ0@JyHh1ylVLkE1miZB3XiC3k@ndg7sPKqsr25BSXb0nJqda3R4JV4RJzEv03TLye4ROnh83NCwGLUu/2@pVKTJIVt6JVANl8Jm/CGGn4lrJHntTquZ1TwaJloxcAGHkuBS3iS9Yy0kSSgZ5N646J60crQZQd05OPZhtO8gozmGu5jXnTacOBnbvj0Z5rUSh18sEY2c@Mjn09tpCWp26V9Di75EIR6gpFs2yT5OtDLhgS53IhWCbCfIDTTl1/5bVUt/OTPf@28fd7@QFXVcrlcUNTEz362OXbGvtmt/wwiPomOEwQiMqwuEuuRe2w6vhiPN9COznJwx6nlxOMUhJ0waYWxYoNo8Fxi7KAuxsJHoxY4PkFAHrX6jtmloxXcCUrTtFrb7AC/booG2yCgjGSpLkdPDEtXOS7Sc5iu5vWNLIVBNvA06kYrzZ1xb6MXyGYE9L0q9/YMFDgMQRpzjbZvj70R3f@dovGUVpbchiiQwtt4OOIahE6TsM8WgAtDP30tKsuyT7FG5W2CB6fjUYsginBvQ5Tw9Hx7Suj@WxrSckBOEDEIzSf16DYg7RakbbMIbeqaoqVnAbKE5Y5FckCF497GbcBUxQORk1ibEKAKPOVtQACUIRUCtlpkk2hpcmZlMtXZOY4XeGoP7mfWo4MGOYyG0LqApjhyFcOBE6iO@IlgpIuwhoHvzTlGQBgMtoavBsonRqc2FOYtIIfJG4MCWKcDrCFaNHL79ixXtZrVTRNaIoR/bI1wvJbWg7M8rwAs0uJvAUsFcSqTwcp@e5HsAOMZml2gOoEdjVmdi0p4tF5wHPzfmGiRIq9UFfWoYgHC@mKtwgCUQWREO6tDg2zWiKIW0yTOvAF5N2im6DFU8dBEc3JLVD@IPC8ghz9LRF/7AmZ1ND8GHtLtXdM@H57HCPcJKGBjegJuMNAZM@iatjXExYE4Yo1Mbz@IYsexoCiWTUP3LA/UYLpUMDqfMaUpaYw2O8@S5oNuX1RzBDcR5tP4orEwNIG3jucFhumsUdHVcKFC/ZHr0AMGA2RNuIsTKAJ4FCTwyA1Mlu2xc4qf4AvrhkaezxGUErQcpHzMMT0w0XVMn8XFFXcdz9SPI9xkidkXiTHsErVMUpTQHFxa4sTg0jQSzXAHtCfEccc2h5ClQ9OkxzD4FUnqg9A37uC8uPTQAroa3LOg@3F86S5DsHRqHVvSER63Lrg9PK2BAgcoICdi82Nr9kDRHNtdYrvuMbGtY5NNbaTmD2vEr5oUsqD4ZAGzsxsQW0GRV9WyOAimZFkouIvwKjJjKTsXdy01TV9/a8paqo01ek57MAtqxTZPdGcOv/Q652aHL3D0bMoaQcUhBXYxZrnQMtkxb0k8eTGZFgH3XZCwaP36EAVjijhlNkrxCT4dnToARm7kmScEB0I47GOAaRrtMAvYiqG0b9MOgLY9aFl4XmTgVaDmMpATr5syoOmFDN4ht4imchgQUsagLAMAA6u@tggd/CAqlsMPulAxIp0nQr4CrXPYBT88jy4kP4wfUTea6emdM/ImayE47HRoWjXCmkVkyc9ZsHUgPdOir4FnAXK4JCdrKT4DYDN8mmeg4/hXozNq5ygvqZDrkLIEIYSoBihUVNCR5eAh1HPf0MOFJHd04M74mQSkeiD609NTkR6NOvYs0fTxu3K@6@i2NOpbIA67UmAOR@GXty1DGkVwZyaBfTZSHA1GWxMUamvl21P25rieXwuX4KaSPT@JneMJfjatPzxB3Qoy3PMpQd2z6KcVjVS4JJjRn9rKnkX0V0nScwaTFwiEEAQzyU6zRhaAZTvGcbb3/7T39ftpI8mif0dP0cHJgGzx5dhOBhvPYoMTdh2TAziZXMywMgjMDCAGYRsm4/M7D3Hf477KeY37FPfWR7fUEsJ2kvk4u785eyYWUnd1dXV1d1V1VfVtb19@uKEJCcBhFB31EhMWz9SPsaeehtO@X8Kd4zrqf7oc/UQ@BQApwacFQdPcQ1VyqX7K39Mh@u5PnFtRms3sZYq@m1gaGTi1JLFHLGHbpy/wCNuM@MTZc4eL1rIdqr7wq8Om5nsVwUKewp3rXqCcShm/L/j7Ar4v@PsiaFQ121q0WSTDV3fYHeR6DEJQJRHMUpW547TDwReCDHK4yDMILLkMvUNX5W6Rait68y8Yx6JiDOCJKRDcSWVbP1y0LtoTz7ndbG9lB8DsCSIEjDiAbrWJprc9/xmpP7oZTV0v9Aq2DxJvJN74qnsluYF5BfvoDxAxBtNriKliB2Pp7cQCgewwQEA5DD6iaFCap4bmvp@7mz4C47QSAY0ZsZZEpk3Sl/wk34G4xKRnwuqA2hogfO93CdCEL0LNHL5FVK0OH2YulFFl03TxISyRS5FsJ4GSkanCa80@DZKGVTqt0ASyo7hajHZFfYehaEU@ad28k@Ovo//0s9Hvw7yIx54YljeMfUOfKhhwACKEnC5EVXFY1MYVMMhu2iNnBjtXheVTuVtDM5tZpWZwO9gF73Y4716ltMHvmjw@lMUiMUkUfFZYFovQxWWRpyXPC0VSJrhfzZPVlooRZH1eQABGLraaI6st9GqLYpEXDrFYU@1WQ3JBSC64CpderEGyLauB9lRV2wsOTxukU4yESAC8PG@jIAZNE8Kzbxz04vjxejxFrUq1Gaw5xAWSh1DERj7rtmNbb2lIa4tWBAAy4gqAHl8wXjCiC14@7f/y1ygmpVqj@JdkA14rgMFoCd43WAfymYx0YBD4E1u0D8DcTWy1jESejgnwfzn@L2Gpl@q//OrLXLhkPvwyZ0X@97u8bCNltQmqSR/53A4uyEZgqdBNFm9d0AYDO4TmMKG9woOi8DtYACZUjDW4MUJJkeJ2r3mB7As8xZk98CNJUcHKCUuU1Md4obES5x6lHKdGBKWbuwU9A9Oi7Gu3HigrQ7AxCnFSPa2ITQp66ZPgrITmxCzBUgqj8XQ4uQ8BOtkjyRsnEVktnnsF@A9wsBRIIBPZL1JEG/NB3Igil9f9FmXEkhOB@FSk8jo2iGAflOMJHq1bieeeSFjfQEUTGbdSOzGN8PUB8ogkVB@Q86aTFNSyEulMgqrCO8wlhpDCIHg08b1CGFBG2VQpYqhQ4N15GbozyFlAVyYDhxQzO5t/ldv71qDeTay5NW5927Y2u8WEgCXInoy969lt76eBe3XTFyMx/fFy0V3@8rMQuzsCc4tuf8PBmPm9YpZCxyhIV3ybo4sfJILfUbgpJm7PKHN2UtCVDxy98FTQ9ROC/BQKKBNGuFRsjhUXolFhXhy39trFCSzC49akvY9mjflWcb6V30rhi2/yJuZLwpqpbmveBrrcabNo03htg1aD13mK0qVHB5@wpxkhc8EcdkgPT2Dp4ALveBoNQdAnZrolhVRGCoKyAgwbQNTv2DaqfdTsqbyFT1K9h0oZUUPIt0MUSvwPHt4I6NEOi8erc7zHAEDiURdIGHSNAOyyL7ZZaXcE9ghLwa490JHAEUdzDE5//3KCjCEvajC4q9QXNI7hdcwCFVc88YedumAY/3E97P50/Fps53Iv87kXeY1keAcvIpjLvNgJtisgkvqwjS4@u/kdwzh2p0t224PNHGHtpBGgJU5ROX4Peplz40wmjlEajdi/z8P7NJzZjdPLGEbd6ZHr6OU1UQTVuGskF2i17vWsy5cwXA4n9myJfIE3xNC1DTD58S/6JY5B1enLSwctA60goJCNh3O2lbg3Q7zsxLf89N3RyL1FgnXR6ML0wEpjB/Y4Y9MUYZSQWAoX0vfH194cpzRajRGgfYlX5HZ9Mkxg8@vCyJAJwxgBKDLcaY1NehFMoL3uyEZVKxOHADSkUUAhAF3rXXede3EwCInPxEHIjqlwDVuNTNadGS7NlbGNqi3IdQGBaVSomoY7DHDzTbUhGrWT5odSvSLg@V299r5arpTF0UfRfFMRx7V3H8kpV7ypnZYr9YbAqNbj2lmzXj06b9bgRaLUgJoJ@mCUzj6Kyvfv6pVGQ9Tqovr23WkVoAH4eumsWa00LFE9Oz49L1fPXlsCIIizWlOcVt9Wm1CsWbOoVVXNCOqJ2ol4W6kfv4GfpaPqabX5kVo8qTbPsLETaK0k3pXqzerx@WmpLt6d19/VGhWBHTPK1cbxaan6tlLOQPvQpqi8r5w1ReNN6fQ00tHah7NKHZEP9fKoAliWjmB7xJaon@VqvXLcxA4FT8dAPEDw1BKNd5XjKj5Uvq9Ad0r1j5YE2qj8xzkUgo@iXHpbeg2dM1IPUAXG5fi8XsGTKKRE4/yo0aw2z5sV8bpWKxOtG5X6@@pxpbEvjNNagwh23qhY0EazRE0DDKAWfIfno/NGlehWPWtW6vXzd81q7cyEQf5QwbtojktQtUwErp1xb4FItfpHhIp0oAGwxIc3FXhfR5oStUpIhQZQ7bipF4MGgYhNvZvirPL6tPq6cnZcwc81BPOh2qiYMGDVBhYAmNjuhxI0ek69xnECvPgRmNVQnGvRcIrqiSiV31cRc1kaOKBRldxCZDt@I2meQedaTUAb4jWPjj3Whbb@6qsbBx3CVqW9ePnPP386rpUrIqHODRPBh3PYdV5FDqb0b7DT@B/hZ@gAoOdcXg86mCEVJXa/GgtVY29gYVYHE6PJL4x7zqml7EYVNjY6nfelTqn@utHpmNZjaobQeKgGpVQFYe2eUqbsI8aboQ0NhcpCgel@ECLU4TcoDvadmSXYCZlKMvW/oc11Yo9BV8xme46shqYQBKzEUtiDZ@5YALAeLo1khcX496BJknro91CyA1VMKfCZbgdeY8@5kOvBP5Nfgx@8OWgvYHVmUTqbHThzRgMUVNUMN0IGJvpH2ndA@yJJ3nOcnwapnN6cM@mZGbw1C70jZR0qO3dGo0HKfKD6pTOIVE9H6xOyaNRUaZw9Di5g7QIZk8/BJMmEHJfMjHqWwn86c/pjKmzYgoaGEmqKTPBSIUp9w9VbuTaSlQ2FIFHzIKPM97b0ffUDKrm57Z39yPs3/nueW@gwiL6lsOG1qF6b/rxpcwGYYGTZBJIMpb0xm9XqgFhGAqVf@BYKXmEhvvUL9@orh/Z1IAkIstf2SG8Td@PZcKFjD@vw63rp7dH5yQksnYjtzqvdl3v7hn@I@b3Ffz9iO@TdSWe4U9jHQU6jT9osOQbBh2aK5oofsD8xcDaLBTGYQw0avUSrmX@1FgsJnAeDZKkD7K6HySAmaAZJOBO6DozMmU8Nxa@xM1MyQCrUVRN7M7YXJOLbICsRD8hD09GSRm2B/yBsf/qrKe53SDKQZDHydwXONZ7wupfASnTS1nevJ3wMgkUyCcXHfCju0wDvChP5gjxGpF@St7VRBMEWBxrnKw071QQknkaxEFIPJc9uaOIdWW2lcklnsfDme8lv8PhRuguQ84DtzUvzBpDxxK@JOnCg6MpOtyTkNgbX4RG1aulAoAXBlEjR3JOqqm9m1WYDoYJxr2idCgPe962y0SZREU7@LQn6NnMqmkIRzr7kWPkbODeuOxLKvrLGyt/KxicYlm8yZqrd@m0YqshH3yqoyBki01fRg@D/iTSJgX8AGidAD6iluVQ8ipIElWkF6isRZXirjBia5SSgpv7qYwDmTh@YK79j0jK0IFcCJIEcnaV68ZGcSPqpGAIgk5voWaDN357r0CXnsDOD6vS3hCmrow1m0h1PU0LuFWqrWIGb3mtbJHZZym6DP0xhkmFWaA2eQlXxN1bcLmnWg8oUUeXFcy/B4ExlTc1u4nlGMOGJS5EieTXZA87KyVmm1gF5cKVtOD3//AnE0ru1FsFNoTkchdZ@aVVThALQh4jPaj8pytAV3ZHrORH/Fb6Zokk@Bei5b8kLHaUDAHoaoIsTwnneE/KuRGd@ixvEiKGT40MATaSek@8FNsLHEoHgoJZbMwOkpW311sd@QdjfatifTzi@hH4WhCqRYR8TieEEL7sEnqH7wMVbewkojx7XbWax7GbDtcStQ1E8bJaQ9THosuu6MxAdbew34GgNl2ZGfJBGB2fiXc@kNwjsZ8OZtEgooR@aQbGJtXfaZjhug1DzhiA3zNHmgvxBXRo79kQ6iAwX6T2RAuZVPHqILExuLYutvEgdBF8OgCbk5EVEPBB7mGSNSjFBpQOWQxQcer5yAbPE5XYORC6Yfrfu7Cfc@1EEmvScnu/npYGEF2qQqhPymOnOuetT1yOLBgwFWkB8SuTZkHZpd3@6Rckb9uiXkp1AQMdXicDXCD3BqCef347PpBIqNhQwrmwdmG8vDYOJVNqWjla@61V@e5dQiVO47tYqY@R7FTaJi8TFxF9SCvJG2udKdMQnXjf9p4/4xDcSOsXnHs4eeIP2cymCIsIos6LNdnWdI/zwvOLD0Jn1dJsoSDI9e4rmN1J93AnxojIdSieKrj33nCVoAN3scJElGJ3U392rSefYHdmDoTu0QU/D0IoFr3j4uKRHHLDBzL31KJ6YEydphXrL4Jms4fJQG39Ljx38GRx0enNnmtKPQOazZQmjZ1GLoWN8PGv19yvi72n0xNmvs7MbVPLrEB6Z6bV3Bbrp/tq6L/Jxlfm0AAHIBe4wcjpDx@QO@jwWVUvuNKUdd6gCl/cV0HC8FGlha5/v1mL8LZCIDnhDGCtkVo489E6gZrYW41ZvYfXIo2PmzmHdKjsYs@ql6LVlY1pPWEW@w1OIgsi/ymlVKWdmb4FeHfiwXE/u7Zd/MvaAwFegn38Rxy1xjEBLXF/OBliTSZmQPluAC7kzD2mNppUYVrHhAHahUQhoZxGFGv68XEcNOlUEoUg6LaxwJc7IFCg@mPYi1YElp7Oke9uTImmSowCKICW8KGctwzo6s@r@NXo7eMTNIXYZXJiOJeSUhvQ6UnWBSpgQMARzeq2jzB6qD8@Y7e3HjlqEgEVJwBAOWq7MVEJJLuiJzXdkz@lYy53BYpyIUE@eSia9uTtNPpJ6a9eO2HPuOFp3zXVE@hRhtiJslps9Im1xiY/LfSOKT4RpwhSjU2zgIVRf6dln8ygRF8UOzrdiZ/kAHdbRLDiT9TcVf7x7PPdxU7zBsFK10fhTinBHl699/32rAx3vrF9BJExWrzq0YnRwyegs@VEDFSGTT6XHU4i4T@IeoUcPKIft9oB2@visJWr0AF45kKlPIZchpCe6wdtjB9elaT8DHUmZ6nzKX6R8gXNhLekoL5@@RJdN/MAAUSp20oEdii24wWBF@IhiLfqpDroF5nElgqdD9tlVnk8SUZ9gFOMgjTvs3tvqLNP59j5DWviQQKvgy@PvgSRfYbFWZ0FQVkgBUzyGFH6PVtamq8f36mv7AuUAAtemz941HsGDNIWdMcUWYAP/6J86C5SBg6ZkzdCMCk@EDi0NMBdASxmMHFZXUfobzpjj8TIeOY1AgeDXKfyzJWugc/Rezqc2Vln0lljElOTm2WZirjSqEjAU/0byy6nIoi4prgDAYYyhfjEPENBJjLDHQ4GR05@HOC@EqBwjqFjM47SEl@RjFviQxHxHosoCO7taiVxciW91GOlYICBYxJcJEAGZJb5IAAU2ulhctBIv4/sTlACBWPE@UxyGQo5KmIb@yDEBKY9ezgxWlFZeWDnJwfRxZ9cMffT5m75@m9O@5qJfgT4@hq10Pvr1VS70NdTs9na4aqgm0MPUWw19BFKYOsL@qvB1/2eQS6DmQK4k3ANNyQhJGdL3C/McgpYJelvmR08coInjUMkYCh4dxqXzpCoq9avDAWshF/f73dlFko4M0BP@q3urYjYUJjLyInkxIUd7Nu6yQkgSawK3euwWarrkTYGGE/I4Af1W6bRuX7xvnpzoSrC4XCpHo7Ez283lcsjEl3oogfLbQlPS0M2GS2f716NRdnr799n7yyyt/Zgxe@S5BaVBOzAkMCm8jDsbcJwN4gBFsXQaCDx2bxzU9a/7fT2gBU8ocfBg2Lgk@4r1BG1AQ9/p5X2Tg@tPgg32n9hB7N8/hT/7bm0WNCUUdQwFtYF6FzcJdXoG5MEXffT98k@qCBguzMqbCfYts3j4CXcQjBOjwSJnUBPNQpL9E2@c0ci1xAfMSPY0QRaVSIWTE71CjovgCSMSBV2MRsBhlnBuhqPgfMrDIjqvIzi1MamoHeVlj5EGdWdQWUxTidYPCdhWoMtb2M0t9Pa1RGKQMKXr/SPAMh8C2o8qPbanqS7RKVoYtno5g4MnwOhF3orVfUJFTLKJSZo9XBqJGo9u5kd3OElB102SBVRkAA0v9WRNcZ@4iYtFvo80zDEMiRPdCfioGnf7X7c0ft2yeDPv9x@3KlJQBQ/sZ62IHFf2dQsinQHQDJTTD@iJ0ZX/SMO0PokEQrGAg6FPq@sOVuhgBcN43i3@fJsqlUri2XRrS5RKR/CASX6OSqKML46ORBkzqODvb4rbu7v7vOaWzU/w8ki9vBNHAINvSO5ezcrwE74VMcANtnvSIp9li8@s/Wed4sHhvpdtlY7a2ewAnvhSqWxJ/sDbprJH9KP1g18ok8lkn3U/Pfvmbh9/t8rt5LPL1rNpOznYRy4DMpSu5251nrYD99HM7NLY4F1Ae0t@pErP9jCTq6wqVHqEsT37CVaXgtjoetkN@dbjOFxaYze6jvbemWASFFDhVQhHVJU3MER@bC/RHA@j03XQAQ/2G0rjSn6gXJ/PVpThfuJqBfxTlQ1CQMqsNw6AxhOOJXSSG8b4gfRw4jkTtIDfkMzL3TMMG/4O5x3Jv9kf5L0PmxcpsZkTm5bYTCToD94BsXlhPssO8W4RLubfDhEcLaCbofCGJOiR/kCRixFyG8YzCoBESCocmgpPrseXaHxW2h@GT8rwdW9gPKELMdlEQodMWGXj07PJHQzLJyhxlzCeUDhjHvN@sKDQkVoMNaadqPjjiyKQ7bEjQNDymAlScKFJPOmDynzml1Vv5FgbFJtJgJGs9dcnNO/xBexFzyimMx/RpTBolIIf@S3ujfscvEto4xduP0CADlRYncxR2EhyI4lnHXS9gN9L6qagGE@9f5L52Ndh6cyxYtD8fwqNCejTE51wzyb0js4x6SPTPzH0j1e0phJclqLt@WTG0KqMr0fz4XQkz7yIRDhyfmt3PJNwRAkQw@EI6sLqDCNDAWY@uHUoDFkfFg49Xoqei13nmSDTreJ0MDN8cqQRIftDCub2r5G5bWaHiIliB@YBQsp35evbw5GHJJ@rvK0De3aJuRYoR7MYzvncjOx5mFMngrHb95HOEGRyOQ/mM3RlYzqzB2PbEhtnbnNmL6uwbYHkM@9mTOjhJDknJHDyyabjuqcQ5h7JISGK@F0hzyGM3h4tZbA5jy2OBg0GDamaCjJBA06CEDsRJZ1fQ2MVoWPA1Z8xCDrKK4u3fxopl1haedHTSEIKugD/0DRbmTqGakGfO/7ESRiMqj8zFS/ISte40Y7p4BdWckzqrdqmmo48HxSwXGL7uDsNnIkd2pymI8PgxCTPsvuC90Wcz5TYg72R5J1F@Zf5IH8AYgVy5A@hBDcy04XbZ5nNeJJKPbnwZHD8hr6PoPCc8X3xszayqjwrp3DwMSXkO58MebGM7FBDpj0wYUZUyfMfIPRH9gDwW97aS2TFi43Ud0@zZuuHi0l7M3Ux@fXiF5MwkUuy2mXTYkMeZqsVS84V2BmzVuin8krzgASYO1FcTMIFLibk1sWn95IEgEg21foh2/41CwhdbJjmZvZigwkSGjLEJHt/e1kEn11BcyOMRXbDeGJummrwU9/lTQF7K/3FMeQXJv8FLJRSSWZ60HNmfQBFMUB0PwEqdtlX27md7fwOaEIDZ5GeOde436a960tnAaKEh@osbD0Xv4S4IUSIu4Vn78PLBfRzOJhgKmgaUU8mtJBLqJzm1I7hsxXUyTBPQHmgcgpJgCEupl/GxsNHVPgtASynylJGC3Yd1Lgvhfun546xHdvDdS0aHcIciV4G7CNCJtQ0QpaMt5ZDTTVdkhRslhHHVw4MMgKB4c1uaLvFxJ2kpbBmZpL7KERj1MwI8/pG5@jKFA3N0GdSmEo@FfnD717@9/@u/bwx3zjczn6Ywd/5xs8be682@BEe4NcL9etm43DjAIvt3W0ss6ADw@PL//4/UP/w7wAHvywP4J/DXQVrb7lxmC5SlV83DvfgIb@9De3@3//6L@jDM9bYMLPNs44lCLF9RZFje0K8C99FFXvJamkyWFbyuLAgDPYwBN0cfqBj1GL7VY7MdBvSq@IG3X@G/bnvjyK3eHLMmpOrEFsylD8FSEZcoYgNpBmkcqHoC813Q7ltIPMGaIp/Ps/seaAB/FO6c/hN@q4bzz10GXrGahEMYIpbBH2eHw5z3yV8945CQvmU7CsRElU7uda@erEP7PDOdebDbthLQk3Xcde@dS4zyIcZp3cNOtXEG7k/zrI3wJLj/ParbB@N@1ny485OCVJ6usz8AoKgzEYCiiE5nVpiBiPgjuEvPGOOEhDoT/wzKZWdA6TsqdNlG1Y4wxMUaTTLlXrd4uNh7E4mEKVT9C8I8JiHRKbV0CLPLyZQs1YviMSWX5DLkc5rIjbvyDlWJh1JszcsZa8FAYb6gNZB1Z9MaTagICSqNQMIXCRj93odW35LGU8SKvDcMp5cOaNpMUG@YdAbvFkNJHRJfxYz10JJD9GCkE7TQoewxs7cBhW9mKA3qI8HLczxhgI@ayXdmFYXn6x9WVZq9b3iCZ5p3dP0LTd9CyOKUkLQjs8zQS6cidCL8dpSRFPlzOngkVpsw9Cap1JgzTL0BzHweFiqfQxLkN2hCEigWtAd6VWmD5tFujDwyK3DMXtsWuQ8YMZGEPxoqRLAWdWzDMpO2G6GG4MF4sydOAX0UOYb8DACoqiStgwnJACtfFaxwxIM9aE2dRhNRSjsiCW3pQnshyRwYCylABIMHY83tcAH2@Ddwwct4WgJfRJoeEmYyFL9AilbVFANR4GSanHjqJmxnarVFX6ynr7MBUR3u@GLRC6//WJnd@/lq28xZvyJ7G08GKyUQS1gemUDDJKoU6Bk4/tiMZFM8CtM6LXaJEKPA4sHcOjWdWsSVvz4tJjPSWC5BMG6pcRUXF2aKwlkAHHmZHBHAB0lNUukUt8VWtix9kXP/BX@S1iqNjMcmprt0fAXm0mvjcM7DoigNEdjZ@zO8HgcF2abMrtgTn3YQviLXtZx@3UH761CX1dme2jo1HUxKGHmXg@udO7IsLVfNGHCAMHns2WBNKjXDkeKkk6tYYWyqDQ4VLXoi6KC11rtATrl4paAMh8Dh2kGkwG9/G3paYqzIwmbEOZ5wIhVPELUXEd1dibunLiiclaOIiYzoQ09H25G92wF4Q72QwBfqZ1g5iOtu02gLkyJgey1WpMsNuiT7isXuByWA65ApsdY6S6m9dKootZqkhvmqfvIkideHPoJ7YKqMI6IVwzMfO5hUqq4VtULJIhaCKU1yV/ELP88RydZgJM@yDhPkZcTBc1H9O3Q8yiXt2wsYUqPUioEA@nxqUQcQLTb5BLckVwBR5QeK5TGikebL3wll0m8I5UH2NdUndiSw740FVDUOGcW8WmB/a@eHVuiXIF/Tj6ULRSUj0r/wH77CbPW45uX@OYLonqihoAIKs1w5HOLPlM/Y4gSMEvO4vQlAYK4@JJhA@uR5I0UrFRPJO15UrdCc7sdcAWyqy2FcGUdlZMEs6aQDeSJVN7JdCZzLUqFvsDGq9WVZksWVtOCTVz3T2yNJk@CVn1ITMpHgNiOgkgrEAG3PwkYnj3QSfK2pe6iGLt6Es/TIZZlhQrE9pMskD3Ms2spcx9bbEu22C7gON7HF8S39/IG310WZo4HeOPpl/FG@vHMkf63YI7Kn8MdLyR3vCjg2sPcMenOHFqRKKKTktq5MRxzuaQ9uNMbDoZoH@prP7ETOUsDQAseXUlmUzxIPod9W7OciFT8h63ofoROQtu7e8YXdn5Hdn6ngGsuPZad/6mdT//Gnd@Vnd8t4F4TM/JStJPhr79djwORMBV@ETu8KO5yMfNLe7one7pXwN00Zpj/8J6mf6eevpQ9fVnAjAl84MApXO/nZpZESo3jajVwt8ioDMQpzAoYz5Um6l54LbYl@qNr76qI0rr4YvxfSfxf4WpET3Ukq63FKPu6PKunHCzPkiVfnIdBVtwT7q8M9dL7KzesQB@RGxQv0mTYmklFBQRyiz8Gp02ZQH4MVl9/83kszry2U24lzgyrKdCsEebNYIqz5EuFVQLWJ8zIc7SkHTfrp1v/i8kwtn@SUWiAPA7tLd4xJHcSXQXDseLXsjNadxB2Q@ocIVaR5CRk5zLa22eXJ@tXNUpsEdkX45UEPmrjdMmYgcrRPIDIZAS0ycj6SqtC11ylXvAb6DsXiu@y7PEXcem3kku/LYi6VAzWkcqWBj/Ji4Getr27e98ewLUy@AcnYM6C8vfMqv8XHC6sun@U@kidzlvH8za0ZFGGnqebywgsI8JlStdQZlbA62Iml@h/8N5PPrVtaNmWQVnxDOP4bbmBtgv7sttz@oOr4Y8/jSfu9OeZN7@@uV0sf8knDEMl50@ZnLVQed9IM8VqvubELBFJ2pzWsjYHINAwn2SrSdgQksznk2arUNhumwLn55jzMfH5QACARNSJN8I7ksjNws8eTkPJHgzR2F6Pjv69OcacA8lSI3t82bPFoiDQ/zqdtwR6g8m3XSAkkIjsMKkurJ5T0zTpThh55URSh1xIWvpPvauzwbjK9jmRSEiU4GeVDgTQ2OIX9S00LTK5tMUmMB9/GfbClhK2yfg1ZWo9VAskn27vtM0CkOkDfUGGv7JHcz4RTP1i@p4wztyPJMCt85gXOdxFcmYocEFD@oA2QL9jpmSO4JSL@6utq6HvWjs@jFYAvh0qHKKV9mMLpr4fugPAYCq4R647OsXxVS1YkhqWeBV0JsiEiGHNb@xR3x8Fla14yE6VId4J95FyyCK1QwMTIYQkRt9f6YJg6its1pWWYr8@HjYAxpfkrrACSscXK60UWOESWkNDOX1o04jW4@H15pxOPKYTAXO2fCQoR3TAb9r7DfF9rQ6jf2PPhmjYYmtbHtrIOBmYnwNy@J/LyRSbqEhOru1dmFc@ZJph5gpy8X1ah3Jq9SXovfIlNkDrDnYAL89VXcDdbEDZDR9G@hEo3zOdQxzKYJG9T2A78tlbMXV@Twp1ySQiLeXHuGkX5m5k7Rn6GKdeRQZb0QGn1x6SS71os7wSfH6F44w5x2APmNnsTrYhzudDWMSXgU8zCTfkMKZLWZSEiIFxbv7oBO5eWeJS/pD5dSSm2uKBtKE8/VdmkGh8TecUsBa7Y2yJl3jmTgzhQwQBDmdA3oxbEbEx/2dWbJvruwulsJ/eqmAZ6XJoUOO7617rCOQe7GdQXj3BHqKv4yuEGLbDLLAKQS210nUY9wb5aZWz8Uiq08HcP50OpVrpdFB@6HSS3AoLE5oQpN17UbrsXc/SM/tqbNuTv2e7npfGi7enc8PoAlkPDkSyclZOYqiV/ykzXcI4pDfTQubpFyRy4BsjkQhHmR43GqJxXK@@awr6ZtCYdN3RyJHigZSRarMe3g9aHnbnSmxiKU/9GtuYVsigCynFsec1CBfuIQ5up4Pu/51OynNGfW10NoIn@O9N8@2paFLCwWalQfkQGzFFEUYGAyBJPUXED56Wa8fNj@8qQMXx6NA4UH@g0CHVO5gP5yPn8CDLf/mdN1@iKLCcOqAFyndZegl1s1z54NLtLeFPb3gj6FMxoY7@CzMHxK3hjbMPlXXaEoJ9150HCGahPgKV0LKMoKqgVwZBrlauiYKwe3hkA4KgUh5wUnkYGDLsL0XyRTIz9EivT5nhluXNJ1IaTfLPDLaYtETydisZs/WHB6LxpgS0fH1aOyqdYsavd5U6prFcNxaXgw4wDUqwdC1DMvyVw9PcSUiooC9zKbFGP4ZLfU@icfjdx/C7Nd2oV15XMZ/jesyZpEXxKVfI34U/3aBPVewXuoSCvt2tYrAGlZPT0ut7sUClbmXfo69oYY79uqap2tnrGqagxNSZ61p0JwPQNAYdbDmGvOozNt3Bizq8R9FbtXxUK99D88GIOxNtFBvD6fGopo5r52frFwfpIpwPQ9kwfETPm@/Om0a4pr9YwYShdcoSC22p0qaW9ElZmOvgH5UaFVE5pYyn2ifydRk5YwXdEkuLFxVQQWntdDwQXSyVqBDFmEI0rpmuVY1djuxL0J@v584@xoEWPt1NF/tzdyofcKphjt8Cx7qmPt31nIG5f2F8uktw28UEMHTi8NMdL1YXkyRfRTNPSUT1ybyCt4@0aUSIUa7Uq@8rZUWPhvY5VBKIVj1WX316dYezLsbNaRSj/DOWzD4TM0KplU2YvhDlGUKSQDBlGAw/o9/VYIZetWma5PB2/9LFzQ924d7w2ivs5p7v@3SRiKw0xyAtfXGMJF2PkRNUh9G77E/s7m/WOeoLwq7f2yEQa0ErvRxh4gr4b/S7d/DCkCN66c7n7jhNaa3V8HKt0HecTKHPPgCYXOtr48eYqtGefAm5V0j2KN5S04xSO59Uj3mTb4DUX6rXax8akdVwhS/t2cy9PZ/@Pqwpcmrc4ElSkFYxgXQTsK4Ne@LCoFWMLrCb@/OSa2nFYgrxUMpSFwaX05kddQnCxMxu00WEwa@vmsxEtLJ7O/mXJBvuHr8rzcJ0qmOlP45QQe/uoVOIc9YSSqP5H85dp9D2vyTRdBb8nai2fs2jlO33rnmBANOsfN@MCi1IfrqXWqc8vvgygq9uv3rXAoGQWljDHhJfH@149e2eFb4/HI3WCb6@irdYlZelRLmmpqb@LdbJy/VKo3b6viLK1dfVpnhfOj2vRMTmGZ4N3Th8kC2bmjkDvBAC6EcnVFrDSU2B6GJoBcXB8TkWBbvhaTjajPq@QdMSfYfDQYbzpMdlDd2i6uf7mbgTJ7Yl1USglxfiUjxFQUO15K9JtF7Rl3CdW7wdtCjhygOhX5Nm1PQOxaRbTxINMxwsQd62eN0q3mO5ahAeSRsaj1KIvgFlEXC@ba4uQlePrb0dV1uSInJUCBLNlRkxz4c754Fit9q57dXOAcG@qnsSQbRrZaDRFMC7H7Ou6/3hiEGbDyMGWuEfTTWMaglRzozo8qsnFOSCsI5LZMMtmgXh0zAZ9PYPZ0mRVGthnKlJu7KiwLL24HrymCmqn6MGB6mLp6jEWysT2HxoCh@7o9Uhy6/tX3I2uASd3qL/N/1dJPYs3rrvkov443trzan@fYDMe4Y7dimMbArVs3LlXeUMr6QR/6h8/FCrl9Ek3IhuDfLi98gQ@p7YZEL1dJuzbmBVFbgYZaOYu@qeKJBjrsTI7cKswJEgYxntxIvgqJHBc/ALPMibl0MnxeognpYJMmckw9RYgcFsIlbXeTpm5g4huJ1VfqBMmvdNXq6O11Os1F0@sm4@pi7mp39s29tr6j@2/Rdx9ckyy8Yiaa9CjPjPco0Q7a@X@hChAWbdAN0/yVeGz/x9B1D8@40gWb@@cvyU0emPGsRXfw2i/3@Xs0dW3omrPHpk5d2YyvPHtrwXV/mxLb9cy7i@qXOVey0Rtdh9BjtLu9tfK9KftCIpu@d9i1L8oKHd769h@zOHjSyvnz9wZIj8a@T@zJFjW/DnDx1aQ/8auT9z5Mge/XUSHBoiI4NIBtIofqi6R7ELt8PuFWjXJADhj/eJkGjRjKAQWDOd1CPIZD62MVQnv0wh/FJd70sZjZ120OotzdZCeaxLxiq01/U67L3xvnQq3tbK1ZM4D44VAnnOHzalt0nR98kWWHLxI3nfxBnNZh02LT@aqiIWCDoJ@mOO4f2xkwz9klqqeJtsw7L9GFdr9pf165mP8H2Wnru3Mxfjzz28YUmFeI/tucaBvh2lVMZLlU9r53UY2HrjMyZ6z/19BtadrqUjmzi/hPtv2EFfrYFRTvIXV57U0Z7JUogZfN5Kxjtoa6ZOiqXpj1w7QI3eYpJ7fr1i@g23kf6aNtKPa2Pza9rYfFwb2a9pI5uNa2TNslSuHJ2/FlnReFP7EF@GvnhXeEEU3u7UnTnOZN0SFl7DoM7vw@uxlvM/zQoY2SH80fBnR6TSg/Z7uRz9BNKJf4@Fvghpg8PDx6MznKgUyo8aHroA7Q8cn8/ZL@LGiKnCxxS/KT3X2OLPamdpMsCHDPF8h73v2aqb5D0PkwRKq7znXs@6@nkKpabFMeIvQWba1Erk1L07GN6mFHag5RAfjPNS@R4o9FWoTKJ8N0g837Jj6hYMeGwjgR/u1zTie7mutBNamJR4Qtx5MYnfTOL7HrtYBt7OrRUH4HYriRgl24ohiRCxYDZ0QOl0Gqt8SjKjJguf7kAmJFDweLcejxgP4FhcY72eV0qu92Ve5fugeXMtQVfGORZeJOTEB77qOm2uiR/zJ4LM0RxiD3mORJdH6BdJFO49cluEUjmHa4ukpUfyrCUnH6cFsqYlFrAE4b9xC/6jXcZjJ8LjBjjeMVy7powuEzbWziNa7kfqcHUjZi7FwghXi5PY8OQXCB5P7TWbo8bXK8GIxBFSC@Az9pXjxPs4n6rGsfUDp/6R9aGvFItgYuPpuT@1k8m7NWsDzzGq71@egFSxgOhmXJyijtvhOtQICdJ2PEkX0DPXl8RCWrxSylw7faeUdS6Avn5uyZ14ilQ5cyfOF5CQ/z5IxBgODE9g39/EXrGRaEoZH22TWJEmsYICiPwzbspOSKh@LU@H2XUdOqwjlkS9UiqLRrMuTs7PjkX1rNHEF7UT@nBaPavEnOos44dF3/4UwVuK2u0g9eOjV94wIN4Q/5VWYdLmFcHl2EtPN2J2f@wf4PIH5hjRPhStFUdZFC/jCatGqPAwDeIrtgB2O1DEh@17AQ05J8a/ARfEU@N@vnhQG9A0gokrvGtM6oWbibMAHcRLmo9do1qFHV6WcK/@jXZKTUCI3SnXix0xi1GctLzGnqeuxPiMgWMS0n3wMbKFVDPVLRnG2nlHBfJr7H6Bm5NcEKIeTqHhiehvpSNYdUvHzUpZvK0039TKDf9TxJkX43SjUbqroW9aCK4ZCc5PXjqD60k0xpRC3ya9R0Lm2NnYsNYM5WqKD3nNdEcu0GgFI7r9Pbk2Wu@4dHpaOjqtSNJEA/YWTlfqsZjztzO151fRHrAaqyJu/WKw28@Skewvr5JR9HQIkW7RYETehXRrWS9SBAltGg9FnnO8OCDtx2vLpoLEOFq5DNMhSG1jGphZ1DCQC0S6K9J5PSD9qRZ1TNfpyLTp/NrC9EgT55ammu0npTX@JwRyPzK8MiejK3NxwZU5iq1kp34Kid4PYiwThzu5XRkP/lBcOJNYpjoKB/mLqTtaDkYuPMMDUDzbc26yk@vRyMAtvzfs98ODoD8ffrONN2I63StXADb/Hw)

Python 2.2.0 is separated from Python 2.1.0 with `dir(0)`, which is empty in 2.1. Python 2.2 introduced big changes in treatment of built-in types, see [2.2 whatsnew](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/whatsnew/2.2.rst).

Note: `repr("\n") < "'\\n'"` breaks Cython3 (`Comparisons between bytes/unicode and str are not portable to Python 3`), so using `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

## 442. Python 3.10.0, 18922 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPJdSD6UTHl/RHJArsBEKg33iBAstnsaY76JZI9Mx4AjS4UCkANC1XoqgIJNMmOGa1DV2PJXluWbFl@jCyv98pX3ljfjd3rcay8G2FvxH7ZcOwn/wDKdtwbtkP6B7rnZFYVABJg98jrDceNW0BV5fNk5smTJ8/JV3V0f/DTnybwIk9ce9q33YAEph@QrmedmJ5I7kzJtm75eVXjOAy14/XHQ9MJ/AqXIAohtu70x3rfJD3LDkwvS3zTJB3Tdk/BXyVkc@yMfbNbB5tGiGOekn3HsLoAgQTuselYL00P/HKE3DXt8@F5QAx3ONSdrk9GnuUE1DdPyBMdLL2xcUz0jh94uhFYrgNehYUkigu2EiEPXc83AZJrmL7vIqzyQhBFJm/rkN7INidXICsKec8yvS6huRh5JsuLopJ3j@7du@qqkS8KrkPuYQ6veOXIzjhw94Or8PNkp286OlHFsqhe9SwAngLTLskl@apXEarKDCzjajolstPrWY5JHkJZr3qWieH7gm941ijgoCrJPcuDatbD6iSG7kC1YaVuEHM4CqZEYISg23ZcyT7RfTL2x7pNwznjYcf0ooB@oHuB5fTJqRUMSDCw/DgeDe2PdMMUuqZtDa3A7BLbgkhuL4QCoJ0uOTanp64HdR/CdB17ChFNw@pZGCXKBwDEKxUMTAZnqE@BcJwAqIToxIds2GYELc0lIPxdszPuE3ccjMYBgbx1LV/v2AC0MyVds6eP7SBLOuAHVULdTwemE1I1gBMBxJHLcvXhmGbNnBG/3u0SGQga8nFsEguwRrNVIZoG7sT1AGsQKspRCIwSOCujOYEahjrruRWSl2Xw34tdMLe67bthZhazhp4ONFpaZwj3ief2PX0I2OiaFKfv7j8hvuF6YIMbw7KGdRMYQw/I5iZJ7j26myT1uFpEr8PFVVQjZ1AFiciTnOj2GChkviZcqB8vjs1hlSXXkhWSBLSoMsnlSA7ab4moeUCSIpfBAIxA1RS4C0QtkZwC7S1PNAisqdC4C@ADDYLkZHAsJ7OYfs/T@5ZtMuh9hF7E5gPRVHjKOaJBy9AKGgvdd@0eC2rQjBSJViKFIinmSRGeZVJWISeYbA4aTR7uAtwAsQzZBECqBpmWVQZs1i6AjpEWd0lPH1r2NEyBJmGQvEKKABXKowB0tQRQ4K1peGtwlxDa4jUPOxhAbQz0EwAv2NYxsjMz5mhYxRK8pI0NibJO5M0seX@AyQNqAan5EilC8gXASA6yAJhXS5A8eGp5yAKE0PIFKJgGd4EVzh@Yth2CGvgIipagKMMNpSkCfkpQY1ATqoyILsINduCoKrBOFfikCqxPBXalqmDWMFkIh1VYgOov5FgyA90/hoRYOmqXVgp0BwBGwVpANqkg4gAC1CQB9GuYUZLTkHgg81AmyEuxQIAwSgop5UipSADHZZlAnSmQL6QsBTi0AvlREBjQhgLEoUCeFKgBBYAqWp5wcxWgaOgPcTWIC@hSchAnB2aoTKWAN8QDilEgSQXSVNXyjHAhb2oeypvXKEWrBajxIvgB3lTIqwpkhmSslsAf45YAhyUk@GIyyxChIx6gprCJAH0CMqB6FAoXwoJZLYYErdujgd7B/oDF7PQwagGbTgHRCFFlLB68c4hNyArUsootBLKvAlVotIXBOxcnbysApIHgza5FmbqNHYsSY6iYpUT6oT4KZmhTCjRHo2kwiN1U5uYCs7WAYZp93ZjGntAys7HnzLWgoatK@fMMkJxDVx@4sTv27RmQ2JBTaVLmiWXP3ErUrWvq3Z7lD17N8pqjiXRMPXCs41kq@Xx2Dqn6nEcBPRacitp82MASoIvrD9A0K4taxDAjN66ghSwrCs1ex@yNnb4plEtz@aM@wdgLoDOapVlmzp7V70PHPoOjZGkxaec6c87THNqaBn1@5IjYxTQ9C7r828QYgMgSe5YZ/HJ5BkNTEcZU76AkIIAIBz1HGfu6njUhndsG7WlmGdQonoyBNYoCV1YGnqtcmsikVJijDYq5lyU5Ztl4tcQPXctJJUkyzV1w0D8xsXS@d4dO8D3s2bCvRtKFvtilksaMpaacqDdNA9IWBQPoqW0UoDqmoWOvjX2YSfvgCI4ViAQSAdnSdE9Q5qUd6UIyPu1sOx6KuCAZdU3PIxgW5GI/S7tlf9zxzRdjlL1m@epBP2@CONDTLTvOAO1b9IAKDfBO@pDedDHbPc8d0g5oiN2u7bqjFSIOdPKnCOi@e2rOsj6TAfTRyAZJC9xNJuhBZk51KqxTyX4@VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KJBTLMw2K@7DoEFsDWWYxixWi1m9rCOXOnAimQWMB8cTHOM7YtisgG5kG0epS1zyR0IWJaYviGeYhEtxA/ApBdHSQxjHnNBcxpNuqSEXCo6hmfXe4WDTW5@7HRR9YKEzZp/oUaq8H3a050YegMxAUzKHlkiFQDKtBrAlQLrBY@6TrOskghnLqgeALhY5LQoVrxElgDU1QnVyIgjWeo5nGHp/mrDMFUqbYyolUV2I5uYIokbuKKOaQm3NgjQVExO7YQKxh2pZDKQhEKB/1Ag9YJXPjAo80mzrcHsiAo1A9FNGAAQ8xa3Nahs9aeyitGxQiyrWm44Pi4ovEQuUNKL/v9oDYTi0oOzAsiDqDbVAkIApip4loiBxFORLQ8NgmFjFGIwLu0CkBed6TSyC2uh9a5CV42gNQO4yx503JZAQ1YQ0hVGC4vR5Q70tzNAAQZNglxtSA5gmVTKnHHzj6iOu6lM0Yo8XCzmzrJoRxUJ3ZffLzpG8C8kHU7aEyiYQ/K8ZoRAtCEaI7TAx2dMAXFsQYTSlyuMQsRs91RXTvuqZPScb1jmMGgIn5Zp82EGhtvRlLGqJYD7TqUHWkC/wnbGQIHxPklhYGkwpp4W3TgQZkAG1C04dKxJrdIT3Q0@eEW9RQdMMwR0FILS5lapYzpyk8voeaAnUVQmCiP@DWt8nmFdqBoDH9zEm5qDlh1kehAqMjxw0HAwQqfsTKKuMv9vRa8hDi5Erq/HMMs5CD5/yKPIxow0C1ibKKcYAMBXmkZQyQIwbIc6gkDm3OG18vPrjNJ@8NidCL08bcKMB8OFGKnTAfq2EIcNvXAYkjG2HVFxww6ILDa0Dr/nAJZDfOpN2ddxUlXQTW@DqgQ9dxl0AFZMZwMciiD60LSoyHyDt0OyZG2lz8hTpCtj0bn8LuDHrS0cj1oGUw1jOlYxC0yuaoK1TdU3GPkRbJncUOFjqOJHb7AfaFEGFk60AL2MSwpYLOpQO/AFbGVGvgfC5LcS7DtNVTWGH@TmkHwIgJelTHMVFt070pAwLFg04aEpoSy/OAGZ5gV8F6oqhLESmdQs@gd7vIXxEdtN1fTVxEit4dd6zJVf3dQEfxQ5870T3SQ9XdA9EDGlEq2fOT6Sp1pzHnvHjJHQUSjcqePASkgUSo8lTPF7GruAeM5nDqGCl@oYnxWcKPg16JT4MBIzJJjbwDCsPV3KESgUQzPIZ2TW1V0odOXBDgKaAbzQl6SCJ66B5IG9AIQdcsl7sdnZwD9/CIMNllCkmkmChiLk7LdLpxWiEiMC/z5RVZEr5nUIMw17dhCTA4LTntJBYQ@IaYoBF5cJCksIdFByrzMT8q3TDHsUPH@0iKCSRpchaLwNABpGhmLBBBLMMK2qHQcvt2JL6s1WpAbCBTAdvspuf12mgsVARODYFFKpOEiYiBexhg20ilobwY@ILlBoQnoNRanZwFAw9aHLVfcBAI0Mo5SMkRYsN6fmQdj7tXK9pBRwzEY6sD0ckyAr7KgQjAWkPtJqwmF7AKum8SsYrEi/Ep6GvES12xQvkwmGf6KATXwqzM1XAKcxDS6lIUsaih24ygd6eGHYoEzASNnXGjDmT/OBwCixlRNpQJokZ7raUyINgcGBzyZOfofi1si8xT6lhOZcHBdg3dps7rGJyP4j7Yv3Owc/Dz7SUwbKtTueogWblSAbva8UToO2MpJ6qV9XkYM8B32zfDxoiLYXgu9CaCO5kTlaYGdC6TCJ2PD754FSUgCSE6aApgxvuKSMPCgNDFdXR/cKUTJv1MBpKMo0RhibBPIpixAbOO/nqUnyfjly@x8q5mahS6Y87ssc4ARI7SvhPFE9HzigAWeXV6rEekcUEWtRyc35iZ5kNG@XkbZeermaEC9RzJvP343t5BjYINR9cEGkTyA5CldK8rAs3bY1DEl4UB9gcmg2TEWcZRqqZ5XYpgw1hA8KxuyQr4AAA1HtElgj2MiuYPIO@7V8tGXQUjpgBqpxCuypXz8pDxeTM6lw/s4gxUfJf1otRj1lnFTkt7rNh3sdsy8nmzmCvPd1vGLM3uPFA6nQD9QCQ3euB17AvoIs6kyFCsDrN/@OBaxn0qRIIqIEQ5820i0rR8m0PtRbBI0pd2QU9zbVN8j3I8nvBpSUpGMwqi4VMVdC783sQKUnKavZU0hIXUd3b21btR4HAwm45nUKUBNXLsmbweThEaPtCI49pu3yUbEIdJh1GCIDatLOZO33Wu1ZCOjljUBM4yAv/F4Rt9BH2N9ZKqjzTWvNLK5it1xz8FLq0UNEQSxRAFJdHw4of6iQ7ompX7cP@DPehElLwsx2aZXoCCuTgUXWgy5lypAxEgITHMz9ICxtOS11p75CHMzQtioUNGF0fcmXkvdaQcU5SWhl@apXfcaxj/0J1eIS1wYaQFhjmU7T968mD/0d7DnfebgZrPL9hzcrkAiIP0OiALiQOGN2ytG6xpYrEQXALahofNC7jAGBSUaJ5p7HvAuEUMIrIMrKAaNqGbescdOEk/fbUwp@grfOgYjIQeYuNjQcOIoGh3bVRGPDbhjf050s8gCEZ@RZKglQ/GHRGUVulDw7X1vkTjQcdg25KCqsv@Yxzd8JfFgMz4U5PFYENcIDpM6Tiibg9dUF7otDmyBpJi4OnYlW31B6AL49y66aXFmIJpaaQuaAigK0tx2SgDpjbAbfiO6olnpP2WopYYXSuympP4KNhC84ewaz0TVKcU9FaAivQVK2nebt4mU@DSCOkqkAQRN@ggh0@wL7AJCJJ07BT1/Ag5lFvgqCnyCoqjF2Mc0wUuJeXlXFEp5CVQy0BNA5lVwJE3YagHxkAIXAHgCW6PjhvMUWHPN3SnJ26EhiizIPfdgqJqjWfNptMCAb15m@YNZ6wb01ZDaaWr5HqUjTB8ugrUu1A8pN3IAWiXGoE06Zus4Gdd/To76@q0dXWJFAxHYZ8jjMjDHRCkXrrAr7vmfNvDCNK8p7SxEFbCwK@kJQNCNkbl8IGYkqBBQU8LpCdhvgQQelE8BMoBvjUXgcxGM2KBaRoMgH9oJLVLTenrEi46ayHXWMwKDg2LoymwPBoImbagYYYiD5rgiEHArCRBBUKJB/2TLAt0IOHIA5Y@gmpiA1q70BGAOufjUGSAXTDO2YzZ2DA2ydCKA547wgdEF17eJFxEoQHw5Q8@64VwYrFNJHd0pDjAwhXJLowokqfIAqAvn5KAjjR0TVTjcdnEU8dCRUTkqK8AXVdyvS0G3hrhIa3LH/zJ5ce/ffn1jy8//tblx796@ekfXX76b9eEV6hj1jczzaYgZhstwievZf7Wnnpr586tOyWaQ5AnIfP/9y/86t/@2i8t5n1Juj/66Gs/@ugX/@aXPv7rzz760Udf/vEPv/7jH371xz/85I3Sdf7bL7vGf/3YDZM8xaGR@QTD9CC5wQB60fsgtTU2bp2ekbW1NYi@trYFNbG2tUUyZAueAjzXoN/cAt8sPLdIA3zXSItctDjQYH2yZLRPpOPnoqkbgzZwS8NMaWkRuryz88k5GQwaExHa@TFvbPCtCzq7RPsCnHFhmd7FSjukK2cw7@9A981ss8yvSrohNRtys9U8SzW7mXTzQsoqLdCy2xY@/JSabiiiKIAb8paUJJ6VLqQ4bxMaEgKJxsCb5YxO2LGFPKhLM4K/Z02gJwJWCYQ0PyZPWQud3MGh1Q/M0WDqzQeIx6tAPsWx59n6EFxGg/xvnr@8ZPHnRaEFHTmSGFk4EAtx2AsljdGU8UWO5bQpLSxPinqsE6E3dANdelcEdUOc62iSa0lJEKAPoT4MEi32Q8s3QLXQHdMd@/NjdEuHDjF1cD0ajIF97w6sEWcaAxcofRtgkniWBJGMEz4CmzaKonUNEW5s1sgycIoBemO6dMeCyqetl45iKDTpE922uvFYdr4weiHGqVVpHCJjQlbfcT1TAERADI6uU6LL4Lh6NJu7T0eKrvHK0Jd2Ach3LTPIknu2q1OMug7Qwhw14lzILD7osxDlwOxytkOEHogWIqsBz@xKGxyd23S9AbBLKA1O2ahxHQ1DD8n1R10xmEBULoUd1Lwn04ZASDslXVVVC0a@V4n8kBYA2QOoGtTiHFAJIy9BAc90WLV7bBgl0mkfPb67x8YaaOeE3RGOO7WHbncMclioZxyYTj9L9oCKLMcdAit1ovgvj@0D1w2YVgyWVSMZTMm0hmNbp2MkV4cxboxnuB3XpkMnN0WdhR97vm7rbNAm8t159yHIxk@PDmtiZS6QpJ8Mb0wbx@2WJ8vwuT8/U0dnKaPpFJ8RJr@e57GbixZaInMJPUroMcSllCArhlo0tcaOYcAzRb7AsCvVjTicQsMxGWmW0JmiUveToNdbcNao87GAvMSeOeeoM1teuaAOeZ1ZoDwLhGstF8LMAyrQMPGSy5XhijQcW84BxDrzKFEPnS7AFHDofsG3TH1nKzBR@gk5WDxhPzDtaALuwBy6OMkEvaSNsxkg2qMgy9ZImtBXjHAugbJpnKGCLkGHiFcFLWhiI4GF5hJrtNl0LEfCiSJuXSLhCHGVNhzQutnMns9YqAuaMR182KyzGWHUPDym9Ehs7Hq9DSA269VowdqqYJhSMhkHo1Bp3iAGLSadBL9W1HhJg0@HpDkapcr5EgjdE1UWmpPiXus8KfkUDT3CN5uTW7L6PsgkuBpx/bbUN6t0PdAKfFUjnyRl2GFfztFQbHjXGAB3IZnJIiqhfsZOz7W7AptLAlojTAvBCgon9ONVkuFiWNPyogWSdIUqi4pcdW5t5TW4V6q0fj3A3GrMGBCKD@T8OHtyThrHWXIi@iPbCkBEQnliEK4qcq6u26TzWbrn6VOfC9eD1MjOwdvvNuQWg8ANdZwfKrFanETLf0Fr89wxLtgGE65qCayA9vp01t7C8oKQAxHoVAJkH2CwBKokTigsEZV8zPNZWXom6HMpk4pL02GWmOkLsWfrQWA6jObYJN1qdLPZlDCZGk1@KxyarxCZzl9YPcgl@EEWq@Tw6O7ewYGIAl0quYfzHBVojiA6gjCyqtARJucLXyG3uklyC@OkUbnloKmBut4O4wNRV4HoxybO5iDb6ZteChzTOEVhgDOdFaIRmTQWIgjXJhkBxVEMLAXK9hYDVlma/6fOseOexjVeAYrPUEwCulO3KyhlpsWxY70QfeheqKAJQUJ9CnqJ2nqKcrJ1JR0uPhviBCsI1VRAhBI0GgR0Jn4dAvOk1aqymXIIC37ghtjleVoVdJV4TYmqvgbOIMhQCGH02ivyrCEL5VZmfRkouhArXODNyj8HFyEsgvbNpcmup2h7v9aQWR7YjBnj3k99uvxxcZtDhawzA89GZmnwaHERZTp0LdLimqLFFUvQyJCV0AELLEjEEhLh8vuQZqk/5fyg9WI06pBKk7MY6SqinJyfUxySdZVQHIJJIawyLiKtGBjTAxdK8yBcej8vE9DWGi63wDbb5PhKrM2Lsijz6MTkdOnkijAqnFDfSDNnwqDlHLt0OiQ2tWVRyaMAGMceHtvXY@JKTfpYCEonUxeypYrF@Wz5w06PPpbEodMB4UQzdaADzaHMC8KiLh3QFx1zvh79yuKKyJnp92zxJu1bwUyEF68JKZRLNHCv07FWBYXS46qp6L0UCwdIwaqYE5VZEa@uvyELiA1Xk4bv//5RFxB8Hf0D6AJw5C02tKFTxqoQlmF2ISpa6GN5zbEB4rFt6RQB1PQ6kIbuQZF0OzYsB00noQUBOvYhDqmHNQvEhw8QJVcmo4Y5ZzNi0Xt5IssmlRxghsaqsFfWI7Gk6PQHKGpdigQm3lgmjUSZEqsEc8KmIOYUZWRQr89UtGiIUKJl9T4YB2P2BGn2tZVojfBejoKFkHJe7yimxNZv31Dlnn487rrC6LgfS6CFJWFnpafjQwJ09OF0aBuNy4vPCsjWQ0fvVcFmnZZ0Sl@vowrfGfsjoUO16i6z0YYwvCEFz2bPVUGscP9bbFiNNcumjzekxBA6EEq4GkDCFZfCHNKsK2i29c4UpYvB56eyeGYdOE7NyGRkbcXU6mi0Oj5qkjR@ubw89kQ0GD6W6fwSW9UZqlS0wOE6z9fUKvRH1lC3BbU7Z1zJtJdNzF8LGs/p0Ti4BYHuQ7iRyLHjMca27s1MN5D4tWHkawPSUedoGS508COiFEVFnTHHaBHYDCQun6WPuYl@axnCou0TQmxa3thdI8DFkSuo5w1YF1uUiEs/58hBdFfhxHBP8V7l7Q9AvWTP5X3Xy6W5egM2JNiGrUPPvJLxLwzr4bDha0jy1PJN@liO2OOlGQ0Me6n7IrFHA3bzA3CvI2Dfsl2fHNLnTQjqe4AF9lxOuvO4tHRHoIPX8@YbuE00mz@rUN3uu3ah1Jd0eKys9bHXQw4fvt@Ul8W8SFFew4siQcd1lPC9koMfS97x6yqIbtrzcCXnnPGGznQZQwpnK1aXDoR73KmwvGT35BKNKUpsUG9Fwrh@5VSfRu@foZNYhdqokxhNqYAMchxGKJfAEHhMaP5ZUsvdnFr3zZjSNbDF1xVirnKPbRO6Jfq8VqVElZXPGUOR5TdnUT17bI7NparD486HZthhvHnicpjd9XAsHYfvcctFHOplqMy9Ue6w50XbjUxDx@m61wsni8xrBPL0CNXcJ2B4gobrMfrOeLRQewt6lXPAUDMYRU3U7S7kAn0@L18pvUbGWZCsfZPeN@o6TDfDpU21vCzLoegxN/exYLlJB9LiuB9a7LmQMHWZpTwLi/Nd3pxxeRoULfOL51ayFHWV6k0Dl8uSYzlmMMXnG3LHjuvan6emgEnihlcX9EyBLhK9qcauiS/h9gcyG1zwcUii01s1rMB6j1ArBPyguntTpc9PzrxRbQo4/TjEqaFF66qRlaeOrQ87XZ2kOqdu@jpQ3IuJozNslah90yANHZ5QxJJYnNVO1@2Yts5ek0LupnhlUVvStsNZT5wlZXOjs5nsxBXeMZpCWa0uqAcDc2hS6w3itd7FUx3C18pAExfvVd4T0zSkyZ5prAowsqBZO/hcmIydk10C1wHFJsAFZqgg2LiEMXRdjayHume5D3YevT0/qx4G2B/qffNepB3MDQngChmmOM2MywcHKuQONiUDooVgQ8HSOTanfvReGvHh1ICKGg9XNjoDhwXfoJWtWvR4vQtzBu7AGZgDttI4tq2iUiCkgAIOqcfpD3CR02i0sPh5Hg@2a9vzeEAWwxiO6/aWprGHmyBx787S@Gxndfh67TCVHrDGh4aVZDowx8DHfTdwR6ZAbauC2jikwZ6reE40R/uzjpXcqNECKqL3zwr/tbpVX3eD0Yi@2iN77NMHjSrQPaqvkyd6bFEFXf7men3xpTvsiKGjGK64oNO4y9t0xwqMAW4SZhRp9t2OMbBel@nwYAIpGtxg1jfS3RAzFhHuojMo9IBebyoivdTm/Q/xtb@q0sNxEtYZxIYb@vdlY1F0G64w0o8Nn437oYlUcOhzrnWxzboVut258mJsBTOgc6tw4oFMNtCOhlV5DxcPrJRE6Gr4GTsMFxWspFIqvKKgKpgyCAjKqmQX12XNNTFNY4@lvMFwjeNexJ5XYjJckEKHuKy5wUdwXyCdhZU0SyVrZzDu@9d5Gxtz7oK0go/VGjldkDo37grdgu6Er1UYVG0Jd6rBuw3ix9i8cWIgf@PMAA2n2ILuWvBqwwtqZbxyeMi2Rj57EqGnrgoWLrABNfPqrBbDzXS5nhhWTNfssXF8NL1OJgP9GoTXPvTngoETvTgMjHyaddqMJzluH/i1YJNZ4CjsKl1p6QKY5dUfd2/C@4/Mvo6rYR9YAa4bXEIVtH0sWzjzWthfGuu@9aUxlGwVseHmezZn5s0vm0TbEngP9b5l3F@oiDiTIYLDRYfstUD@6HS9Lk4Hlo8LbmLDDWMuSHKMiJHq2iBCLwl5dfA5Pndg1oDYXraloZcNELujKW75mVLTTWPDVkAHEMP3Ki1q1fKmGzNxOh6Oxn74Wp4HuqRnfoB1yNiZf2oBcOEFcE0y0O1g@SDs3GgiCFJhfzczLk@yQj6wbLdPPijJBOSugFgo5y4hnDvQ8z7B9SKes4QSadpvOHeHOr/A5Db/BdStiSvTHSu4eQAjCHDtSPTGwrBOwT0FeeABPsXtzwtBOFqOkQdznVy8j/Q1XTRQ2KE79gwTjfHhEPMSeQjd3I2Wvlq4nR4Ptzid12wM14ZmBAZ7adMwXGccCN7YuZH7F27k/hU8IGiuuknqS3sPn6bna50uEH6dIBkdITUzrZzdvkJMlgOy1Gp@uRg6EvvvsqNtDug61dfE2cHzdwzKlu@6y1SQJ1PoKJYx8/HwrmngXNZr03jkPnQdF3qXETC@4YHJNmIvrDJYHhGjPcCtxoCH7muTOaRgV3QqTHrQR2YH6tGemd6kb2GA7@qBvqJrocNeVCWLTa@lCcvumN6HdDxrzrxKa1zM0H1zQtWA1YTB2poQGAaTXnGoaaEtLEwu@CPXddiTck8ZXsrDm7kEsHb6ePPZWxFXey@o3ktVqcWiPj5hSxfMLjspYFVZPbPj2ux5w4IYx2IT1bpnmb70ADeeU7dCjgggTfk38orijbxipsWAZHqi@3TmeLlWMAOpTD7HupSB7hkuTtqEhhuWjMztFn8NO44XkLPZ7A4gfgKcSTfG4dmOr8uWPewM6WOlAjBXmwcmJNPFlWqHUyfQJ9crkw2@hPvL55YZxbuyI7aEjbpAUk9Au0gvV@CuYM8a0QflvCtncOlKEcGxTOOljgNNLsXLbHh1wR/KJj2ixhXDrXPNhQ6ESjrdZry0xSyumwJBxDaFYOCBGi4FN43QRmdcLBnSHw9NnPdcnEhYKXK6/oAW1l0@xRszUc8UwuPWgGfER68xuU7YWSkxInj4P77zjgSdaruQi859ABb1@kllyPzYc8LXm1DaE9cPetbkMeQbF5evYhtYrDxEgRdrAWjaWFUIqD1nbLMBgf7cop9hl6pRAj08VxBsypYDUzCdE4GewjW5XiKX7RuSdvBQ1cDsCuEmdBwsFx5EW4jiYOF7yZzePA/EFYWKxBA7KeTCNYbLkHsacQCQn9xAGPn0LY38J/sPHh@JI19Z2g/tDHDR/TW5bGFXu1qS50aJPtS9uak5thaqa/mBdOdQEXYf7IsYYAW@2ei9AC@cXFp4rRyKjA7SlPSV2gv6msFyge/@0cMHmdmOO5LaHXju0EzPe@8eHmZxA8M7h0u952Pfg9bRcycro@/vKUp6CfmG2zJXccklKa2CdGSCFgnEeJ8divFaIcpwR2b3aDoy34VOEjm1/4bJF1YW8pF@YvWxFZLySkTRhkrKYiGXnlv3C0qy6cXvVfV5bI2QWxr0JbHXyhUSKCFokqctlxJumpy@Kq0QOZwc/3yRFPk6tc4f5Srp/j82Y4qirMLzod6DeiX5lZW1GGDZFKftnrzBbKgZKiNC7CQEQFWC9drFykVhCKxbwgeOmIeOYOysXJlxE4DYubC0wZ@azlR3BJSWQpeRG0sZH5hzczXxYpETPOd56bRVvN6apAxqjNB85M157e7e2Y88Dph7aHv70VPyRPdB41kC0ZyDOJMsPhRwvAaP71o1cLHf9YBTs36iP1pO9xVyqHtd15lO5poKzuJiV0dPrIzjoI0GMm1rYi3j3QYbn3myfCVIlAZbIe9OF@S8@RMxwgiXX/lVRZFlet4JvhWZWa8QMEmhSZ/iYVnzXkf7Mekb2C@L4JBeqlU9MCe4YoCNUi5TTpfy78INvL2YXs0ub/Ir3eCXuyG9a37oiJsplBsA5m/wI3kx9n7g2qcDV9zVPfMGdNyU9fINWS/P8ZvwCGY6exWaVwutuBI8fC2ltyMz8HKjgduxcgsi8uLOyZXD7YHu0fUHfTdcPM/sy5M6HUcN@aH@0pxvwsczPmAOxrhkfMlEWgcEMdPpW@zENXLHDfao7QZtId4Yunyu2RrdHY@usBI8nP4Kd3oPlDL31Cd3cKvPTD5colzi2qLl7quEKRKPMOHhgvePdqJEHx9K6lyKs1y8/2TBGTfDBY8P59w8czJZpW0Jk1XKy1KfWaqPjnILyW7Wn528Zl8F9GzA6uL3yi6X8Z13Dq@3TtQUBsHQjnze0R0zgtN1A7o7Kh6Hm4xmg6PvDSgBRHxsyYIu6EUsC2D4UruNp5W026uo5Mh8nw4sQ19JAnOCYj0T8MNDgcxJbhCE3@ugUVY2APc45tqHo4HlTELLcOaOa91I6kM/KvEOObTdUxIpPHPNJ@yxIIp@Yjo3b2oSytrNHbI23@su4Imd@h@@VqHozore@47pecvCHBjSvcjyrppeEuKdwyjAMt9d28VB0q41Hi7zplEzmWVe3kLDvhrJWuaBh9YfD1zPWeYZVUylcsdcCXrtBr/hFLS1ZR6dXm@Z857vLnN@OLYDC4W0yPORO4bWE5HVnhdJb/XNerMpVsSZFc/g9Qdeet4FOMXQHfsg3ll2@mpQ4UMrWHC8gm/qhocAm47ouFfhvuOSL1qzfM4X4uVKLL1zb@azOE48xplCujtuZly1U2o01V5Lvi@tPrUsJzzHGl7xnZ2vtO@5DrOl5@d9otOVlkC7r9tWevVEqPqamVBkc8yfnGjLWhkw/HvzGH13Ookl5yc23asb2nZVKEDfMNLhNyJ8uvpS0eYGBdiSkRXL3mYs@0t7Q92YH3JcOGQhmjbyZ0x8TrPwDh/d2Tl678mD0P5FfdiJUojORVfvslVb8RqNK8Mo9OR46RCfgj/Qoe@iIygCbpu@MoP23s6DJxE7HoBIDqjEw93mBppivktSXc/Xh@VYgnwY7VO6C20PzTNOdH9qusI4LhTr75ap@St3D1w9HOrm0HNHOl2rjUdmcDj2eumVG1nV5crO4YNVbPWdqJiHbz9850v3ZtucHllDIosq/K@0DFER5atO6nUn7bpT7rpT/rpTQZSvyHwrpEGxdNPmZU0sX4etXMu7ej2j6vWMqtczqsYZnXOSrzstSXEJtpQwJttIDlLD/FH9fjY8MoodvMC2u/ti9D2FVMoBZp1e/KzV/N59PNA6tY4Huq7TffoQ9vycrIV748GDj3bbh6cB4LmPljM2cTs/@7BNUFuHZGo1JV8mW/jNqApRZJomfmivzI7XixJrkPWzcKd7paJckLUa4Ss8Cc8aiE/LZic@A2A8qxYKRYRjhawH4LMe7ZMn9BMm5JzQcVjBwCNBwSZK8yeGVMOTBCBP62dP9p/sHR7tHD09bMiti/CkgagUjgOpReeZ3NK6PBQ@xBvov@z8d3rChQ3J0e9W4PitH5WL4CebFotWWyjarFD8FsZZP3McSaKHLUjCBeRP4Flq1BcFUHBisKMS0woKz9mosHMP6PENUEcMNE/ThEqrEHlZwiPd96FYof/Vr55RX/xqXgW/m4cJh0d2g7zbd91umKJvktdfUYr3dvYfPD3YI1EGZ1RzanWDQa2cZye6h4e58Xj0gk1PJUmGUZJQV7Va8l4SEJMUk6RCj8egp6njwW/JmB7wYI0w9gZJrVP4gMFkXCnSf/9IukiKuGkjDWGTUaaSkCzQPCUUPPruCIiE3D3Yf3fvgGD@9@5SZ0QRgiBHuIP/L77fZd8jiU7Mir4Y6A1D/Q5qy3etbgUPzDBMksgpanjqTpfgaXHsTAliTui3PSjl0cGluW8IpukpRtz8KR/R0Rez0zmw5igHmI/JvhtCT72IP1gSf3eJ4@ipfEDvp/RQySvnLabpmWbs@4jsJNQYNCW96NsHOPkK@iiVSSzfwjM3sB567ti70khwOzw9XlQkO/gxRfxko04/rQOZHTsBO54tPLIpARQqxrwqS9ZpZtmHePi5gMnNNWgkHbNvOcR3LBBBgwr5ECgYJz4r7EwWQagnr0WJQFeoSUClcy4gU5CHeMA9EUZ7eM5e05Muf@WXpH6VgDkA8yeheSLfAdvXQlsPzF9n5mcSEqiUvPb9lTgv8xnC81fDErCMcD3rpz/F76vyqXVFOW57J5lkXq7CQ6nmSZ7cWm8KwnpDrm2v64DI4MWkCc1Z2sidmHcHve5@X2ryPMipOUnaODs7S97beGI9y5OC0LXUwovJ9EIraC8mF5pSenE8UgoN8cWkxZdq2eNWs9EiT568/6r9Ks1PTujwZAoIbPcxr@T4RKVMzrYKWuK4jN9egxIek5dwHfcI/qn5ZXfOrKO50wO6TfIk0Wzix1D5Ig9sL9mCP@UUz@FiPKNRF@viVuvVq3RD14PJlFiWNfK7XbjdAUmpavqQQFO7DY2IRZBIk74pEuHKDyc9Mtkx@/3xnj61xveCbbEolkR1jjFtPvzgvfCqvvf0KSFPydOnLw9WsLFWJpMShAY1TyLHByA6Ziek0tbzCfx62l98tnaRPXvS3vyLj4eSuYavx/j65OIhmg@V/K21tVt37uRyWVVVmfnJB09@fmdnJ3c3m3/SyG/lBHlt88//bG1NVTdVaa3l@0or2Tg@fp9X5Rwv/sX3ku0nT77k@3Xtv370qq7gowiPE1IkZbw0ooARnyW4FZLPkze9Ei8TClyJKf21E5H72RpR6lvF//HNxy8SQaKuSu958A4SLxKFUoIZwQA2LbKdJOqJTQxWuEhMpVqtBsbi//h3EL/@DsBBn@kmPOr5CFZhmqgLNRrlPFEvgEFRVUj3//noo7kcAj8DVlKDFimUIrdtYIiNBp8rqvxWC64Nem1yeFSRIEtSFM4JBoHpEqV0W7mNFgss8HLgheNLzQR@P/LxNhGfHWSgT8iI79bXpLubAlziSFIUtakot4H9Crc2ajUB@hXabDUtfxuPkUzT3rDvBi4xb7@3cCXe@59yLQVTfe@f5jogu5Zhem6WSxTWtp/frdeh5Fpd26hn6BU2N9ryiiXedbeB6xwNxp7l4icpqw/w4yp1Xi6pfDab3T5oQxQymSAyhclEbCMIwj54nWCX2CbMBRt26MioEq468oQWid1ZrMg6C0eeJxvQWlrPV4dL7OH1l//hL7/9l9@kv2/T@z/hiU9O1@pJGxDoBBpOHa7tSsWo1/m6x5810V4HapMrpUpJal80UxuNeusABNy3z5N5LUkO7Wm2reCvmW42aPw6TbYeJo/2emLmXGcu9Xm30IMFpg7wDjFFElE558oVY42QK@G4RLRYSWic1FsCjnfWhIZSyLcEFquxDZXDq8Uy324lhPUp8CS1VVfz6mOyXWcXGaz7xMXcaGohKkiY3/qsbDOfma0@75SoR9HqszCfN1yYpzKUzJdC2bMeZXR7rbJWqhQqqtSur76qsxh40aCmaT7xEyeJ@KqSkA4jfCZiypxzezZfE3G1kIiAyULc14TjEo1ao2W2oI2E/2UXrS6toPDV0KS2eVIF@lA1Qe23eVmB1rbdjtj5Flxr8KN/uGIrPteoS@hMg1y/1khF2VA1KX@rsKdiH3z1Ip7QqGcojxRa9YyIvFIQrwTioFchRqfTeWl0QEbR9Y5u6Eqgj/WJPtWDzrgz6QTG2MAvDZMnKOi1Qxx4mpt3S26EElFIaHllPXEbKVxTy/jRXtBSSiWtrGpFRSsWtKKslvJaqawVc1qxCAC1oqqVyzlV1QpFrVDSCgWtUMYPI0OYAoTREEIxr5U1LvGqsUYOGH@bkEx0NTOvvZ6KlKPhRQ0u3oLgThIgQo2N4yyX@Ce46oqqkA3oJmV4gGxIjUSlPyjhrm6N/SxHEiD2nbVebTRebZD52hLCPMNLbG@3MsLFRQPM1Wr436zHxiq9mAmK2rrIZDaf1UEaelZvZADksxCkKBAKVGzXSWuTesWphcmF/putVh98MyO/jyQj0Ey8gExkNhubNXeX3iJtnUILUtlcyPn2NiW1bYhVX4duIZ3JrAvCWgNAN8IOCgIjQYZFBEgQLAWizNnZz3iTzU1gMhebF/WLxubFxeYm/Dfp8yJ8g@sF@lwkc26y4G4zS/inr9l1cbHgG4WZ@beQTzUbUr0pNUNe1QK7KNXRRZSaYKjDG8I1NLXUwt4R5SCx9c/zL2Znz9gFs9wSIddcYoNsJPCsJC2xwSWeX376f@DdvPz0ByjTEviZFS5xRgiXkDbKhLrRVxkEu4cOecguB8x4R1Z0QYf6Q3R02MNBTVmSnoukIlB1OaWUCmkRu/@222vjZlSRPIegEGyvb0Ijingv4dVSgW9nlKlKEpt8oUjZ7c9du5LJ5L94rpaLSaaN427K577vP5zL5SyfELiqyoqgnNfZobfsVPKfW3b9i59bdXGJ8zJBHKUIwwuXADJKSBJokVyivjnEpX34RQ8BP812UntfeLoj7LrDkR5QdR3H8kBUqO3v1crlOqpR5voT2ng27m7AU4H/3hoUgjR7ELTZqxlDENGbPS2vNlFrfVsH7R0YndB5gb8HL/FHjgz8HbzAHzl6ib@DAH/kYQd/Ry/wt9PB39EQf3de4O/hS/w97eOv@QVNU6r8un7SnXThP3m5Plk/o7jKKGXlYn3CM5wlturNLwA6/WSVbCe/0KCjQvlyq4G@LfD4QuBNK3qtXB3V1Gr4zQrXz/pTP4uLME0DkW8atPdM8eqWCkJtuspoRMuVSfoLbIimwpxeCWEs0fJnXwpke3QroGmmcQxEK@ddT9CJ5cMDHDJaWXG95E@@8fHHyVotKSTpwe45cBPwa9HwAIezfEVRs0pFUbIKPLWsWqwouayWqwg5pZxVS/BWwbVcUbI5EHmyipavaFkll6vk4Fmo5LNKPl8pZJWCXClmlVK@UsoqZbUCcWWAXYJXoaLIFw3bhCx3LS/l@ukMvpV0WlDzuVYmp@ZcD7KfS38BEEREk31lqjoC5HGJGllX1hXZlg1Z6SgdMFhE9og8kAdKV6Gap2wSeSpPiTx0lS6YTPjJYLLkHpH7RHZkB4KBL5iCthygqQevPvx6AMiDn4XLmzqKbBBIyEbtlH7fCWRsPITnvE3eHrh@kB01uQZJEv65@fz5cxxLFwtWC0/7b/DPnzeljZZaLhER26HYbjxvJlt8k8ezYNVyjnSm5lrzOQ/SlMyz9oouJOH7jWSrmpCaTYmRANQSpbOLi3Z779HddlvCbr1JzHpmOwN90vZ2Dfqo8LWVqFe3mhXa60U9X0La3GrWNQHNhQx0YCq4kfsm1EFWynzOawYY3vU1ioDW89PnoLylTlGFOz2B12lkeK8JjzZT7qi3dPpec85KDXBhWEl6bwmEBQPk2vGmsaAGf9CF/6n@1j@v/8OnJJ1qtNKps4vNFL3S@Eunzy7OLsJnPZ1KhZbUJvzQAewY5eyijkYa6AxMjVS6lb64ABNwjDN8p9KbDCRE2qzTyGckDnlGEnGaNF32SP3PeZO4NKnwaiarz/nNTc84b1YpR83JZZLgn4Mmpc/mSZrNiQzMoRMdUi04ZF0/p4PK6aqBX4Bb7zSU1p9/jx5EvpWmgfK5alXZIMyi5tRqNRfZiqVqtRRZ1lOp8vWrLm8pBWB@uVw6Xa2CZSsCK4MV4jbIqwypkSY8W7dvs0RK6vl5BFPLFTIyzk9Vq1FKeUjW9HWDNnRQA8/2H9NDvIFT5BMEGUI4wp6S6UcATnQ7leQr/O3bqfAzr1s76du31bJ8fh67jEbgpCw4tdvAa9ttdNfOz/k2T6c2ynmwy6Xzc0UuZ5QkSbte6hF@qxPSSgkKuaXWabJlYMxqrgjeyeZEKSjYkei0IymU8Ax9c@Sl@KbDp9dqfLLZdJI8@uW0Mv3QsQdcnNqx04EnIoB1kVXyv@hK8skqnzijmFVKRcZW@So6z09DAachZxcJSmMkl0@ngDOnQRy/SODPQybO@uZ8Pl3NyXLi7IJngZVymYVOk1whVcqUw19tLU3qIGuyHwrMWia3UdzYxpFDn16T6xfy@eqZWVMuamdmBT9Oc1E1wo804vZn8/ZtrQy1VpIT5O4YD2HINrmwk6iB3IFiKzyaXDKZIbduc7g33EtWqtuU5qB3JolklTkKSehsSAmqX1I38koJUcNZPTzUAGQvTqGYWSNrnErf@ODKDF9r6JjgEjFLft2f68JFuqRD@niRPqr4xCI2vYhNmD99GkYcyGVX6BtbaVw6KBC5mPHFpji0vMbaVZI8GBsWDi4@ebCzu3eUVTcFklDv7exm1cOndxIKWvMzO/XW0H6wt3P38VOI8OTB3s7h3tv77@49fQLuPjmdXXGfFvVscQ83Z1piPyXvcR96L3XT1M2xabZPx@PTF@RDy2pbUOX2GMrm9j3im20o0kifFa8Kt2H5@ocf6t6IXuTyu1@5/O4vXP7eNy5/7yuXv/ftn3z67a/A/X24v8He3/ijch6fP/n0V//g8nd/Dxz/E9x/CvdnP/n0Nz9iN7X/EO7/Muf2w/CeC8duDmB97SeffvN7P/n069@B@3fC@zvX71/5bPn97S@vvjHeN//g5jDf@Hdw/yGDFYX9xu8yN3xfC/@7LNzXv3P56/@e/f88/KHx9y5//Yf4CC2//J0//y@XH/9HVS39@b@5/PI3L7/88eWXP7n88r9UL3/z3yjy/OMPLr/9x3/9J3/413/yr@j/@/T5h2/yv/zOL//V//lX/9df/Ul4fwb3vwfTZ3/1H6EZ/90ffxf/3/zjv/vT7@L/f//9v/vjb/3d1/41NfwWM/zD7/wRe/7o46/86Mu/9qOPP13x/MqNz0/fwP3TfwKXN8/nm8B5k3J9XpdPf6b8/GOwMUsFaAAo9xcvf/OrQLy/Dn3U5Ve@j3sx4F7x/76q0DDfZ7b/DxjU62VGHxlMcH/r8ivfIO8jlv43wBL8yfvvQ@/0ftirv//@@yEGP0E/cH@fOrJrMSLzjHxnPp@QWTioht8mpPH8eQunjxdAU8tPPv2171FbwqzU6dQg9voltZTZALVto1yO5ww3MfxXY5BfmP0Si5DyJc1xnGqYg0@Qiy0k9gnyv8vvfnT5vX95@d3fuvzu17D/F3Ll7E5WUF4zBQsB828QDgMW3iQcBoTk2xk6dipkwGyeS7hZaPuckCqUQytpzVlwU@r1NirwI/CoVDbOssJWE8RKWuILGhd3G4GEqgjqrczWmkQUPattaDoElHIsHKk423IuU9zQdYlrn0u4M4mckzmjpLCQkhriknnhqi0phCwpauy1HgGIi8ElMpjdDJWINiI5La@RSSYsySScpkd3CDTZoMYJYZMrE@o94SZ0Nj/6z4wTjmSokEQv/PpUZKSGMF60EqAId1iQPKSVmc3fUOmRMMFtg7nQRQ408RwoUnReNDOp1dGA8w7gdQfUllotgxFrLFNgZfmrlwjNTyZTg8JjbBYn2y4hiMkdCgVi1igeahMWMYPw6hFOMhw60dxkSrW7kGBtchcdMgicgn3@vFYv1SZ1BPeKISUzydyheUJgtcyk/grsNQoT4nGJu68gK6VaJlMvYYJYSFZH2TarqTwtHC07zrCzioA3LnPb2ibkFq@UeDZ7tYYIY6HxmZmFxoAY5eA5r6j8cz6nyjwEbmY2wrLRf2Sk9wbF/hpNN0ySlR1TXqPASPv5xvMwIA0JqQmCKIoEblxSskW2yRbHsJbJ0MzAKxMikRILJY7YgVBMcRla6wxtAB@c6Tc6iarmqqCfVAk6eQaHn/Si65Rkbn2Ca9DOSCgzy@F3Ki84HcLkZI07O9fDNWrrOrkApwKHIWiatY3PfWFmEWvr6@tcos5r/GM6F5@RJOIdV@hKQ2h7VNOqEL5Q5tHZpMsuGRYf4haELEfNVSwmufzoe4mcXExw60n6TWDCEiK3Muze3t4gtwCt9D3nNqEL@oSM5ubcBEPjZibDq5Bo3QXbBkVhhkLjnpFEDf/gnqDkBr3xE92z/CyXpYwvCy@xlkBv8vjx4zC/1OFZjctAO1Q1Be04DzsejyG62cU1D9msKGbFbDZ8i/RNHcTQIFLf8C2uI@rJvEaoFEv4MVDHGCBeuFevXgFtcIiLyr4ThEZSU3Ml6kkoGUxwqZ0@zHLsqATbnkYretVcmWMjLUQp5AhJUYqAK01w6WoKaDzNsfVvjLyiK5VUS6UkDQk1JqYgGANTUJBTsTXCdFMUyRcXrJCzeSuOnbIpBVyMES/OZflLlfLpyHP3Mdl9/PDh3qOjUavWgt6Gfn3WbI881zB9P4WeO4/uMvpVy4U0znxj6Y8qKvJObq8iIyFn9u8e7B9WCMNZWHkpWpIqXckQYqascInR6L3NhIcTG57J47eXXP4Qn5UZMlJqWYOoiTqXMExU0IBS8Q93lRyYfSTgh37/jjshKTnL81mlgGp1GpcaQHZ@3h0TPFuRHegA/AFXUopQYsx5/UyYm9pDhzo5UDlmEBRqIFq5FBmKzKAUCxjgMfssmcbVD/eOAPLRY6KoskgO3I4Fmaq/TyYiIcAFDtyh6WaFCxobedKRNXQxhF2zTacfDNbxU698U@bnELTekLP4UzUNnkqukFXyxdbamn0mIJwmJZozXCd6AdYzAXHyFlyEe4sjb4ETXMIF4dyR6ZBwymT/cZWRL24VJinI/WHg8UoeOEOaw8mgEB43mr@qiHVoaovTqlxi7YMPAlKv7z26K@zfw9GLyYBEq0wFqysOREo63bFnUt8@IV3rXQu3MYhdyx/Z@hTaMSBsow4YCXDOO3FxcdEDmPv3iFpXqZXF7eLzwqAuHTBfTHSOAI/ucYnb0YANV7xdqdReKbki5K1SeaWpKgcO3IbEJazeGpAbXSe0IbEf79RyipxRwmkih6R5nq/6kClNK0kbXELheXhpmsbRNkS4iskRuo7slVyrCSGbzyl0GRmHJ87rk5oaX2HYya1ZWE1mYdEHPEg/8Igc@RWZX2iLegYoCi6sph8djYYw5du3NRy20nJyXHZCUUMuoE7XtZxGK@me6QRIZwR9W4lcMZyohHK2EpxtBqRbA3OiiQWn6bKF6vjhd5@MIWQhB0zxtKIqdM14JafmEjzB0MgqtZLMJRoJ4AFcowW84H/5r9XgWpN/vn9AS6NR4ybAS@fv0BnD0Hd4cdxD9/Hs//jxcN5643/42H342B268Ife8iEy@ersX60uWG/@h7wV2Wu1ClkNzAnQG/xych6s//Dtj/7@1//D3//GJyJeoS12@Idvf4u5/86v4vNb3/77b/3C33/rN6jLr/z97/yr0Osffuf3yV1gAtOXOtLm5dc/vvz0jy5/8Nnlx799@YM/Qev8/9N/G3p9/K2ZI5jR5cr/W@RvfuU//@1vf/LXn330t9/67G9/649/9NHX1ZLyo49@6W9/67O//tOvEbD/@Idf/dFHX/ubX/r4Rx/9IoSb///4h59EXl@OHcEMLtf/4A5wuf//uvFCBo0rP@hihs3wCM463ZfQUMq51h7wuAZpbUanc9Yh9CbbfUjweJUajwQoBRZz4@u@afdEXO1f4zdHdU1W@c3wiO86edd0sA8J49e7ta5r0A90V7uihR9Kx312LF4ux1ddBw/iq8Xz/ySVPuvXTun@@apZ64t45Ivn6DZE77jdqegHUxASDdd2vVoSVN4kyNnvWq5NqRjMO13XQRnWqZmgZuFkw5am5SpQPnHkjrbUfFEgQkORQfDEWyllu9APelvQ/1bU7Jq5VSxWuqJhm7q3la/k0duI13ls5eVKX3z/4YP7QTA6AInJ9IOtXBki4LFpeMDRVqmSzwNL4flMg6bYwi8PMwFDWFuD/tjUuwK8cRmIL6ilVoWmX6slk1uaogpKRZNLXFjYGcKcqiPklMKWXAnm0Uj2bMtxvSzP4QdS41rAChwo9Zyc25TgTaDucU0KiFN1smP2TeyPaM0pm9IIaQKMEFQHYweM@U2pA0YLjOVNyQLjuK4p8qY0BqNRzyngajAqwdogVrcGaWLJMpjtLJJLdqCchfJFxXEd84KrZPWsdUZrrtLr9S42zjIzC0ls03Xo6pV16Gegt50JLBzU9oWgZztnsbUqzCBwFTLOCtbME1z0HhDPWbg4p8Kr@RJfbVRn9mKBr7YuuO2h2bV0/Ox1Uz67HqsAIiGDmoCEmoS7qHiuG1Q6Zs/1zFlATSlEAVmGrgfI8Rdxck0ZUzy7nlxhLtDkbIbXGJ8d2zWOw5To1yCXpZXL8xecEaLDM7sXLKFsJRs5sqiUbLAasUITz55xiY2Dd7V6Hej2LFdUc/lcXtUKhXxRBfG3nCvkS0A2ckHOqyowj1y5VC5eQKuVpFcJ@jk5snsWteYK/aBASq@wYzYbLZJ@9ciyz0qawNhPKl0FcSnxikvcOnhXrddXj8OlQJV4VxXqNS1fBpOGJlWjQpWqCqomaIqgaPh/jUHF/5uHV@Gv4hNiaSp3hIcQPQIpHhQYhzzAc1QClxy5Lt1xdsc0VoTYHej0wKNdz/X9f0SYO7pzzLzuWuzE29jrvo6fXfOHVjBYEeLpaGg5Pm5b@6eCsDfsQAaR27MAd@Dh2a67LECRPH0Cj4P9t@8fxe/lpX4YnyEPyGGHyEOMo72d3ftcgdx5/OjulVc@BJcnD/buHcXWIvONouZjED@/9@DBVWv4yj1@etAbux7e3L3HT3OzR@yEG/W4HFyLgWJnCiR8oBVFPFRVyBrJFyODwuEewdu5MrkdGvOFmVFG43tsF6Llx9sI2UbWCncUbU3UCXYBHZPgZ6rMLh2ipUcqhiMbSrHMcSPiuKekKJOua9s6fge@twaOA90nHdNENd22kRIx6VPXs7unVtdcA9EY0igr@M1tzAR3H4AMx8YAEwAtCQ/i7eIX2nHJRccem2Q8Iisd4YVOaPSs/gAkjVM3CsB1dJ3A/XkviG/OX8HNDgFLg7pd87GvB@cS3M5jHIBJlHh@l@fv64EuFZ8RlJ8G2VLF4YM838dJbtsPuo2NMWh4a2tbuRJRm/KuTJesTXVJkaqAR6VwXne3lY222a9V/HxB2cIOuSZnthP3zVKpeg8unvd1JwucMlvxcTjFsZ4Ro@qoFdDwR8UNQprmud1sTnLVZLKmqDKpVHKVPBva3NUpmVX@5re//@M/@9blVz@7/MFvoCRI7rqeoePKdlTJCVWwQ81cpCNCarmUL5U1tZQtlUu5vFLI57O4mrJYKpblrCIrJaVQypeVbClXBhEuVwbffLkY6vWStEF2bBzKyzLdXdqoAHjHwO9Rb9LBJXFQ5xJsJQ95mdLTJKHH9jHhTYjDkx2nb9oAA0cFA7pBdsOqQQdOFJloRQKQdWKQxL17uzLi6Q5acGnjrszzXbTkS7JcvMPzJvXZLaGUyrssTgkPWeQDZpHlO1CXYwYAvyvA8wO07BVwqobnLbTs7rD66KFFxfgQ7Jj5MIsdWYoQzEGLpjEAL2JoEGyHpZOjGd1DCyaJPveYzy748fzbUXbQ54AFYwDuRyXd2eH5fWbZ2UGfXVrsPMvoF9GyQy@e98ACDY3n@2Doe9DEeb4DRmxuPG@AyZjq4IbfAMcj6Z1A5/kpQw8iiOcnNLRuHPN8O3LHZN4Nc5NH7FaoRWGl3qaWMv54Xo0yjcG02KLxfC625KBs9@@/qw@Crtln19RjbwNKev@@pluT8d69zttvd/r9jjfd2Xv7AL12d@@DaDMde51@J4zYacPlQqzd@6p@PJxevaDU@@12RbeXen2x3c7pzhWv9rRtYg4h1gvIWXj1MaFhexe8du@3t/Ulq58mFGAbOc0Q3h287gzhfUfvMK/ool70Pel0@Co0A1BomikOdTBcwYTN8xg4t5Md6obnVtE@qRGZLrCfNgpyq0o9yBCUKLl6gf69FD51HHlPn00bk5rcqk1qRZWNt/VSfHOi5i0@uzbcUsr5ypq@pai5zKSCe/vdXpIkBWWLpJTbGy9J6lF6SwVVao1vbm0JfENpbRWKz5DLVfCxpSqlSk5WSZpZtWIF4shJmRB8pBvF1lYxX5lFLhYzuqRWikUQAgE/AYgSHRzqbpNU6tTUj9NpzDodKoXy0IKTKS20Ve2lJtlJjWWSTNPVSU2psnOciXwFWirVxY8DjA08RIYwoH0AOAFdClfQpXilXOIhD5KECzhxAI8h5ywnly7Ozvyzs@ZFzColMM0Gq9/70tHx0dH7wK1ANpmyMb56OMz7xDOR50UL5d@@vyvuP45seO6/eA/FZNcTd5HHLfgweTlyOgJ1SrwPHTyo0pEbxAk81xb36Ip6kLUjj@jwHTE8m1c8ur8A53DgnrKUIZJfRXFOx1MV8LMIVpfotTqY9C5J0VwRPX1KRYt2vV5r14bmcBRMoYhRrC8S@s2AGZh9n@WdfqYFP2JPo5/1PHcYerRr8kW1U5skJoJAdkDSG3tZgNiuEUF5PnS7z9WMUe3idxHu1O4gmGob3p2qWTM9z/V40GX5am/LqY0dX@@ZT0wPj4rYf7wOIg@etJLqETO9Tpp7GHoXNawLoe4RZ5bHR@NhShfqnfSiE06NxA6IptSXouKf4dQA5JznL6q9Gkk9g6AvwO6tk1RXvJPeylUBY3dIOw1O8vPe8x5RSSFXpQpRCmFBE6SYQgzo6Vr9iyCpMdDH0GtDbsIqPwaomBgAhtqgPnp6ZF1UjZpNUgKZpCmOctV@rYHRz/GxKYCkIQiN8xbObLyHWsKLMXSedWju1WlCr/njDv1SDpE7ICYUqhNwU4q56gDqW382qXq10dgzqzZYw7kQQkusVwG3gEIA8/I8dfnVj9KbQr7G3KoU1DkOYLfFdm1SdfCMU6CUmlYDj0wjJ2fzpSw8ilkQIVTcTZHVsrmsUERXkB@y@Sw4gkIGUlLKTvGE8Fl5IotKVjGVbEp@bnWfp7PHKZRrKPLS2cDdc8ZDgi5QZUit1A5vPZ1RNwBFXZfomwIlXmAyVSwX4H5ARlZ2QCEdmLrNIqQFom2k7PUUBlo/Go/2Gq1KZW8y@hJ4pYQXW4VMUc68TKerqbV0zTdf0HmjOxYQiA7IRc5Eiz9aA5oO54uIPx42oNbBpBTVSqPRwbIW5awma1BMq33e3@TrfCsrrxUUqLMLOi2gEMZZ5mdIQHLiZm6jNmoMtgl1qJTVKkf3kyTIHW9Mp2y0kiqUpfxGXmbTJAwENwpZJOKWpJp8uBsnmUomi2oyOVOv08kqTkmv8bMZQqp00zXGqSSwbJK8reYLWzwIgHyFL6s8BJtxXMwlkaOcb5Bd3fR1D6eSOBy0IDlQ2s@4i7OLzTo3Ebm9oWVbehYEWgM/OWcZxyJ3z/W6WdKx@qSnB9iWRW4HSrtfEblD0PhMamrs4WcHCItPD0nBaK0QYIXOswWD6cAEtUjkpnTaMRCvu0ItEXxHSS2GIF/gDvGMjU31Gf6Kzx7uPMbfve0E7lMh218AvzK4l549fPr46eN79ByF2fbmz3Ntc0Sim1EmYruaqNLRf1yjAclg0SqfY1n4Ns7EE2kNDwggGVEQ6/QQim2WSjM8DklaI@Tz7pbJbNafsXcTN4gCaI6eed4gLbpe3LRQYSfv6iBQbpEkVLnuDRuqqrUaahHEEui6GjILqqpKFXLRTtDdznWg78kZZHozU8ejJr5IplM9I0RFv03q/cy6rE4TJ22@UNboaQjtuiIfk7Xk7Q38mLdAEifHa3V1I5N8UtEyybtJLZc4STXX6xllmpTIRkad9nC1Gq6LkpIQTjU3bmkbyaeZSqmfrSgZfKrwrCSJsJbYbme302Wfo5RMEgsIXivv1Hb6BzvRKvud3XpJnYZHZCSetflSMcxicx1QpmaebS/Er4Ms9AzncK/U28@yB2Abl8Mnq8nEWZIkkhfJi0ayBaAbjfjElVprln1c3BeugNByBZJOkHRoK5YTfipefvCF5HYiiXP8xPdfAUHTeqDNOjoM4YvPVWAyCceNHNxxgOO9IEbl8ziDnZCej/wP1JL2cP@xc9e7Z3KJ5tr5mourE0iVZyB58sp550ugxkJtJUmzlpjUcuEUsFKvC8qmigegFUkFBICeUhDk8zrjZHXqUVDB5/Kr38lNNktgV2UF7Kqaz6j1urIBImhidPnpDwJvSs723t15QJI4ofzjP/ueWvzxn/0@XUSfvKCTzKpWTEBINCqFYuLsbHR2BgLgBfPLJ1qJawsCW4AmSdHLxQ2xWiFSqVTeENtSgqETROWikk74QiLcWlHIC6mUIqnpDa0kp8HnPDxkKqXKJbBGiz2oE1/I8@nE3oGVV5XtzS0o2ZaWU6trjQavxOPiJP5tmn45wSVKD5@fEwIWo97t9y2VmiQpbEOvBLL5StiEN9TwK2GNPK/VcVWjgke7ROsGNvBYCFzIk6xnpI0kAT2b1BsX1YtWhi4@oOMfzzac5hVkNNdwH/Gi04YDP3PDpz/TpFbq4IM1spkbH/p8aiMtSd0u7XNw4Ycg1BOMZNsmydeBXjYkyOVGtFaA/QShmb786m@qauHHf/Yr5@3z9vuqqpbL5YKiJn76082xM/bNbv2nEPFJdJwfEJFhdZFYj9xj0/HFeLyBdnSWg58cs5x4nIKwUx@tMFZsEA2eS4wd1MVY@GjUAscnCMijVt8xu3S0gjtBaZpWa5sdoNdN0WAbBJSRLNXl6Ild6SrHRXoO09W8vpGlMMgGnhDdaKW5M@4t9MLdpqDvVbm3ZqDAYQjSmGu0fXvsjej@6xSNp7Sy5DZEgRTewsMJ1yB0moR9tgBcGPrpa1FZln2KNSpvEzzMHI86BFGEewuihCfa21My0j3fpCEtB@QEEYPQfFKPLm6ObUHaNovQpq4pWnoWIEtY7lgkB1Q47i2QLSkWLBA5ibUJAarAU94CBEAZUiFgq0U2iZYmZ1YmU52do3iBp@Y4LqAwOuiPw2gIrQtoiiNXMRw4geqIn@1FughrGPjenGMEhMFgK/lqoHxidGpDYd4Ccpi8MSiAdTrAGqJFI7dvz3JVq1ndNKElQvjH1ghHbWk9OMvzCsAiLf4WsFQQpzIZrOy3FskOMJ6h2QWqE9jRlNW5qIRH6wXHwf@NiRYp8kpVUY8qFiCsL9YqDEAZREa0szo0yGaNKGoxTeLMG5B3g2aKHgMVD000J7dE9f3I8wJy@NNE9AUuYFZH8yPhId3eNe3z4XmMcJ@AAjamp9IGA50xg65pW0NcIojj1sj09oModhwLimLZNHTP8kANpgsGo/MRU5qSxmiz8yRpPui@RjVHcHdhPo0vGgtDE3jreF5fmM4aFV0NFyrUH7kOPeAvQNaE2zuBIoBHQQKP3MBk2R47p/hZvLBuaOT5HEEpQctByscc0wMLXcf0WVxcd9fxTP04wk2WmH2RGMMuUcskRQnNwQUmTgwuTSPRDHdAe0Icd2xzCFk6NE16DIJfkaQ@CH3jDs6OSw8toKvBPQu6H8eX7jIES6fWsSUd4RHogtvD0xIocIACciI2P7ZyDxTNsd0ltuseE9s6NtkER2r@sET80kghC4pPFjA7uwGxFRR5VS2Lg2BKloWCuwivIjOWsnNx11LT9PW3pqyl2lij57QHs6BWbPNEd@bwS69zLhxI8ac@R8@GrBFUHFJgF2OWCy2THbOWxJMPk2kRcN8FCYvWrw9RMKaIE2ejFJ/g06I/sq2AGrmRZ54QHAjhsI8Bpmm0wyxgK4bSvkU7ANr2oGXheY2BV4Gay0BOvG7KgKYXMniH3CKaymFASBmDsgwADKz62iJ08IOoWA4/6ELFiHS2CPkKtM5hF/zwPLiQ/DB@RN1opqdnzsibrIXgsNOhadUIaxaRJT9nwdaB9EyLvgaeBcjhkpyspfgMgM3waZ6BjuNfjc6onaO8pEKuQ8oShBCiGqBQUUFHloMHQ8991w6Xk9zRgTvjpwuQ6oHoT09PRXo06dizRNPHb735rqPb0qhvgTjsSoE5HIVfw7YMaRTBnZkE9ilHcTQYbU1QqK2Vb0/Zm@N6fi1ciJtK9vwkdo4n@Cmz/vAEdSvIcM@nBHXPop87NFLhwmBGf2orexbRXyVJz/lLXiAQQhDMJDvNGlkAlu0Yx9neabcaepzQBgnAoRbNyBEPDPYiy9CPTNaoF4dwA@SjsVfHPqYrCwASz2YLZkmzEkYhp5E1tI/@3/a@fj9tJFn07@gpOjgZkC2@HNvJYONZbHDCrmNyACeTixlWBoGZAcQgbMNkfH7nIe573Fc5r3Gf4t766JZaQthOMh9n9zdnz8RC6q6urq7urqquqh6iB//EuRWl2cxepui7iaWRgVNLEnvEErZ9@gKPsM2IT5y9drhoLduh6gu/Omxqvm8RLOQp3LnuBcqpjPH7gr8v4PuCvy@CRlWzrUWbRTJ8dYfdQa7HUARVEsEsVZk7TvsbfCHIIIeLPIPAksvQO3RY7haptqI3/4JxLCrGAJ6YAsGdVLb1w0Xroj3xnNvN9lZ2AMyeIELAiAPoVptoetvzn5H6o5vR1PVCr2D7IPFG4o2vuleSG5hXsI/@ABFjML2GmKp1MJY@TywQyA4DBJTD4COKBqV5amju@7mz6SMwTisR0JgRa0lk2iR9yU/yHYhLTHomrA6orQHC936XAE34ItTM4Zs91erwYeZCGVU2TZcRwhK5FMl2EigZmSq81uzTIGlYpdMKTSA7iqvFaFfUdxiKVuST1s07Of46@k8/G/0@zIt47IlhecPYN/SpgmEHIELI6UJUFYdFbVwBg@ymPXJmsHNVWD6VuzU0s5lVaga3g13wbofz7lVKG/yuyeND6S0Sk0TBZ4VlsQhdXBZ5WvK8UCRlgvvVPFltqRhB1ucFBGDkYqs5stpCr7YoFnnhEIs11W41JBeE5IKrcOnFGiTbshpoT1W1veDwtEE6xXiIBMDL8zYKYtA0ITz7xkFfjh@vx1PUqlSbwZpDXCB5CEVs5LNuO7b1loa0tmhFACAjrgDo8aXfBSO64OXT/i9/jWJSqjWKf0k24LUCGIyW4H2DdSCfyUgHBoE/sUX7AMzdxFbLSOTpmAD/l@P/EpZ6qf7Lr77MhUvmwy9zVuR/v8vLNlJWm6Ca9JHP7eCCbASWCt1k8dYFbTCwQ2gOE9orPCgKv4MFYELFWIMbI5QUKW73mhfIvsBTnNkDP5IUFaycsERJfYwXGitx7lHKb2pEULq3W9AzMF/KvnbrgLIyBBujECfV04rYpNCXPgnOSmhOzBIspTAaT4eT@xCgkz2SvHESkdXiuVeA/wAHS4EEMpH9IkW0MR/EjShyed1vUYosORGIT0Uqr2ODCPZBOZ7g0bqVeO6JhPUNVDSRcSu1E9MIp@@XRySh@oCcN52koJaVSGcSVBXewdKK78wwCB5NfK8QBpRRNlWKGCoUeJ9dhu7xcRbQlcnAIcXMzuZf5fa@Nah3E2tujVvftq3NbjEhYAmyJ2Pvenbb@2ngXt30xUhMf7xcdJe//CzE7o7A3J7b33BIZn6vmKUAMgrVFd/m6OIFieB3FHSKidMzypydFHTlAscwPBV0/YMgP4UCyoQRLhWbY8WFaFSYF8etvXZxAovwuDVp76NZY75VnG/lt1L44pu8iamUsGaq25q3gS532izaNF7boNXgFZuidOnRwSfsaUbIXDCHHdLDE1g6uMB7l0ZDEPSJmW5JIZXxgqCsAMMGEPV7r41qHzV7Km/hk1TvoVJG1BDy7RCFEv@Dh7f0ebTD4vHqHO8RAJB41AUSBqXxh132xTYr7Y7AHmEp2LUHOhI44miOwenvXw6QMeRFCQZ3lfqCxjG8Ilmg4oon/rBTFwzjP66H3Z@OX4vtXO5lPvcir5EM78VFBHOZFzvBdgVEUh@20cVnN79jGMfudMnOe7CZI6ydNAK0xCkqx@9BL3NunMnEMUqjEXv5eXifhTO7cXoZw6g7PXIgvbwmiqAad43kAq3WvZ51@RKEy@HEni2RL/CGFro2ASY//kXvxDGoOn15EaBloBUEFLLxcM62EvdmiJeN@JafvjsaubdIsC4aXZgeWGnswB5nbJoijBISS@FC@v742pvjlEarMQK0L/Ha2q5Phglsfl0YGTJhGCMARYY7rbFJL4IJtNcd2ahqZeIQgIY0CigEoGu9665zLw4GIfGZOAjZMRW0YauRybozw6W5MrZRtQW5LiAwjQpV03CHAW6@qTZEo3bS/FCqVwQ8v6vX3lfLlbI4@iiabyriuPbuI7nmije103Kl3hAY23pcO2vWq0fnzRq8SJQaUDNBH4zS2UdR@f5dvdJoiFpdVN@@O60CNABfL501q5WGJapnx6fn5erZa0sABHFWa4rT6ttqE4o1axa1qqoZQT1ROxFvK/XjN/CzdFQ9rTY/Uosn1eYZNnYCrZXEu1K9WT0@Py3Vxbvz@rtaoyKwY0a52jg@LVXfVsoZaB/aFJX3lbOmaLwpnZ5GOlr7cFapI/KhXh5VAMvSEWyP2BL1s1ytV46b2KHg6RiIBwieWqLxrnJcxYfK9xXoTqn@0ZJAG5X/OIdC8FGUS29Lr6FzRuoBqsC4HJ/XK3gShZRonB81mtXmebMiXtdqZaJ1o1J/Xz2uNPaFcVprEMHOGxUL2miWqGmAAdSC7/B8dN6oEt2qZ81KvX7@rlmtnZkwyB8qeBfMcQmqlonAtTPuLRCpVv@IUJEONACW@PCmAu/rSFOiVgmp0ACqHTf1YtAgELGpd1OcVV6fVl9Xzo4r@LmGYD5UGxUTBqzawAIAE9v9UIJGz6nXOE6AFz8CsxqKcy0aTlE9EaXy@ypiLksDBzSqkluIbMdvJM0z6FyrCWhDvHrRsce60NZffXXjoEPYqrQXL//550/HtXJFJNS5YSL4cA67zqvIwZT@DXYa/yP8DB0A9JzL60EHL@JBid2vxkLV2BtYmNvBxJjyC@Oec2opu1GFjY1O532pU6q/bnQ6pvWYmiE0HqpBOVZBWLunlCn7iFFnaENDobJQYLofhAh1@A2Kg31nZgl2QqaSTP1vaHOd2GPQFbPZniOroSkEASuxFPbgmTsWAKyHSyNZYTEKPmiSpB76PZTsQBVTCnym24HX2HMu5Hrwz@TX4AdvDtoLWJ1ZlM5mB86c0QAFVTXDjZCBif6R9h3QvkiS9xznp0EqpzfnTHpmBm@tQu9IWYfKzp3RaJAyH6h@6Qwi1dPR@oQsGjVVGmWPQwxYu0DG5HMwSTIhxyUzo56l8J/OnP6YChu2oKGhhJoiE7xUiFLfcPVWro1kZUMhSNQ8yCjzvS19X/2ASm5ue2c/8v6N/57nFjoMom8pbHgtqtemP2/aXAAmGFk2gSRDaW/MZrU6IJaRQOkXvoWCV1iIb93CvfrKoX0dSAKC7LU90tvE3Xg2XOjYwzr8ul56e3R@cgJLJ2K782r35d6@4R9ifm/x34/YDnl30hnuFPZxkNPokzZLjkHwoZmiueIH7E8MnM1iQQzpUINGL9Fq5l9txUICZ8MgWeoAu@thSogJmkESzoSu4yJz5lND8WvszJQMkAp11cTejO0Fifg2yErEA/LQdLSkUVvgPwjbn/5qivsdkgwkWYz8XYFzjSe87iWwEp209d3rCR@DYJFMQvExH4r7NMC7ukS@II8R6ZfkbW0UQbDFgcb5SsNONQGJp1EshNRDybMbmnhHVlupXNJZLLz5XvIbPH6U7gLkPGB789K8AWQ88WuiDhwourLTLQm5jSF2eEStWjoQaEEwJVI096Sq6ptZtdlAqGD0K1qnwoD3fatstElUhJN/S4K@zZyKplCEsy85Vv4Gzo3rjoSyr6yx8rey8QmG5ZuMmWq3fhuGKvLRtwoqcobI9FX0IPh/Ik1i4B@AxgnQA2ppLhWPoiRBZVqB@kpEGd4qI4ZmOQmoqb/6GIC50wfmyu@YtAwtyJUASSBHZ6lefCQnkn4qhgDI5CZ6Fmjzt@c6dPE47MygOv0tYcrqaIOZdMfTlJB7hdoqVuCm99oWiV2WstvgD1OYZJgVWoOnUFX8jRW3S5r1oDJFVHnx3EswOFNZU7ObeJ4RTHjiUqRIXk32gLNycpapdUAeXGkbTs8/fwKx9G6tRXBTaA5HobVfWtUUoQD0IeKz2k@KNXRFd@R6TsR/hW@GaJJPAXruW/JCRekAgJ4G6OKEcJ73hLyr0Jnf4gYxYujk@BBAE6nn5HuBjfCxRCA4qOXWzABpaVu99bFfEPa3GvbnE44voZ8FoUpk2MdEYjjByyaBZ@iObvHWXgLKo8d1m1ksu9lwLXHrUBQPmyVkfQy97LruDERHG/sNOFrDpZkRH6TRwZl41zPpDQL72XAmLRJK6IdmUGxi7Z22GY7bINS8IcgNc7S5IH9Ql8aOPZEOIsNFek@kgHkVjx4iC5Nby2IrL1IHwZcDoAk5eRERD8QeplqjUkxQ6YDlEAWHnq9cwCxxuZ0DkQum3607@wn3fhSBJj2n5/t5aSDhhRqk6oQ8Zrpz7vrU9ciiAUOBFhCfEnk2pF3a3Z9uUfKGPfqlZCcQ0PFVIvA1Qk8w6snnt@MzqYSKDQWMK1sH5ttLw2Ailbalo5XvepXf3iVU4hSuu7XKGPlehU3iInEx8ZeUgrwR9rkSHfGJ103/6SM@8Y2ATvG5h7MH3qD9XIqgiDDKrGizXV3nCD88r/gwdGY93SYKkkzPnqL5jVQfd0K8qEyH0omia889ZwkaQDc7XGQJRif1d/dq0jl2R/Zg6A5t0NMwtGLBKx4@LukRB2wwc289iirm9Elaod4yeCZruDzUxt/SYwd/Bged3tyZpvQjkPlsWcKMC6jF0DE@nrX6@xXx9zR64uzX2dkNKvl1CI/M9Nq7At10f23dF/m4ynxagADkAncYOZ2hY3IHfR6LqiV3mtKOO1SBy/sKaDheirSwtc93azH@FkhEB7whjBUyK0ceeidQM1uLcau3sHrk0TFz57BulR2MWfVS9NqyMbknrCLf4SlEQeRf5bSqlDmzt0CvDnxYrif39ss/GXtA4CvQz7@I45Y4RqAlri9nA6zJpExIny3AhdyZh7RG00oMq9hwALvQKAS0s4hCDX9erqMGnSqCUCSdFla4EmdkChQfTH6R6sCS01nSvelJkTTJUQBFkBLdnLOOYR2dWXX/Gr0dPOLmELsMLkzHEnJKQ3odqbpAJUwLGII5vdZRZg/Vh2fM9vZjRy1CwKIkYAgHLWNmKqEkF/TE5juq53Ss5c5gMU5EqCdPJZPe3J0mH0m9tWtH7Dl3HK275joifYowWxE2y80ekba4xMflvhHFJ8I0YYrRKTbwEKqv9OyzeZSIi2IH51uxs3yADutoFpzJ@puKP949nvu4Kd5gWKnaaPwpRbijy9e@/77VgY531q8gEiarVx1aMTq4ZHSW/KiBipDJp9LjKUTcJ3GP0KMHlMN2e0A7fXzWEjV6AK8cyNSnkMsQ0hPd4O2xg@vStJ@BjqRMdT7lL1K@wLmwlnSUl09fossmfmCAKBU76cAOxRbcYLAifESxFv1UB90C87gSwdMh@@wqzyeJqE8winGQxh127211lul8e58hLXxIoFXw5e33QJKvsFirsyAoK6SAKR5DCr9HK2vT1eN79bV9gXIAgWvTZ@8aj@BBmsLOmGILsIF/9E@dBcrAQVOyZmhGhSdCh5YGmAugpQxGDqurKP0NZ8zxeEuPnEagQPBrvKYNWuYa6By9l/OpjVUWvSUWMSW5ebaZmDGNqgQMxb@R/HIqsqhLiisAcORFdjA/8gABncQIezwUGDn9eYjzQojKMYKKxTxOS3hJPmaBD0nMdySqLLCzq5XIxZX4VoeRjgUCgkV8mQARkFniiwRQYKOLxUUr8TK@P0EJEIgV7zPFYSjkqIRp6I8cE5Cy6eXMYEVp5YWVkxxMH3d2zdBHn7/p67c57Wsu@hXo42PYSuejX1/lQl9DzW5vh6uGagI9TL3V0Ecghakj7K8KX/d/BrkEag7kSsI90JSMkJQhfb8w2yFomaC3ZX70xAGaOA6VjKHg0WFcOk@qolK/OhywFnJxv9@dXSTpyAA94b@6typmQ2EiIy@SFxNytGfjLiuEJLEmcKvHbqGmS94UaDghjxPQb5VO6/bF@@bJia4Ei8ulcjQaO7PdXC6HTHyphxIovy00JQ3dbLh0tn89GmWnt3@fvb/M0tqPebNHnltQGrQDQwKTwsu4swHH2SAOUBRLp4HAY/fGQV3/ut/XA1rwhBIHD4aNS7KvWE/QBjT0nV7eNzm4/iTYYP@JHcT@/VP4s@/WZkFTQlHHUFAbqHdxk1CnZ0AefNFH3y//pIqA4cKsvJlg3zKLh59wB8E4MRoscgY10Swk2T/xxhmNXEt8wLxkTxNkUYlUODnRK@S4CJ4wIlHQxWgEHGYJ52Y4Cs6nPCyi8zqCUxuTitpRXvYYaVB3BpXFNJVo/ZCAbQW6vIXd3EJvX0skBglTut4/AizzIaD9qNJje5rqEp2ihWGrlzM4eAKMXuStWN0nVMQkm5ik2cOlkajx6GZ@dIeTFHTdJFlARQbQ8FJP1hT3iZu4WOT7SMMcw5A40WWBj6pxt/91S@PXLYs3837/casiBVXwwH7WishxZV@3INIZAM1AOf2Anhhd@Y80TOuTSCAUCzgY@rS67mCFDlYwjOfd4s@3qVKpJJ5Nt7ZEqXQED5jk56gkyvji6EiUMYMK/v6muL27u89rbtn8BC@P1Ms7cQQw@Ibi7tWsDD/hWxED3GC7Jy3yWbb4zNp/1ikeHO572VbpqJ3NDuCJb5nKluQPvH4qe0Q/Wj/4hTKZTPZZ99Ozb@728Xer3E4@u2w9m7aTg33kMiBD6XruVudpO3AfzcwujQ3eBbS35Eeq9GwP87nKqkKlRxjbs59gdSmIja6X3ZBvPY7DpTV2o@to750JJkEBFV6FcERVeQND5Mf2Es3xMDpdBx3wYL@hZK7kB8r1@WxFGe4nrlbAP1XZIASkzHrjAGg84VhCJ7lhjB/AS5qdCVrAb0jm5e4Zhg1/h/OO5N/sD/L2h82LlNjMiU1LbCYS9Advgti8MJ9lh3jDCBfz74gIjhbQzVB4QxL0SH@gyMUIuQ3jGQVAIiQVDk2FJ9fjSzQ@K@0Pwydl@Lo3MJ7QTZlsIqFDJqyy8enZ5A6G5ROUuEsYTyicMY95P1hQ6EgthhrTTlT88UURyPbYESBoecwEKbjQJJ70QWU@88uqN3KsDYrNJMBI1vrrE5r3@AL2omcU05mP6FIYNErBj/wW98Z9Dt4ltPELtx8gQAcqrE7mKGwkuZHEsw66ZMDvJXVTUIyn3j/JfOzrsHTmWDFo/j@FxgT06YlOuGcTekfnmPSR6Z8Y@scrWlMJLkvR9nwyY2hVxtej@XA6kmdeRCIcOb@1O55JOKIEiOFwBHVhdYaRoQAzH9w6FIasDwuHHi9Fz8Wu80yQSVdxOpgZPjnSiJD9IQVz@9fI3DazQ8REsQPzACHlu/L17eHIQ5LPVfbWgT27xFwLlKlZDOd8bkb2PMypE8HY7ftIZwgyuZwH8xm6sjGd2YOxbYmNM7c5s5dV2LZA8pl3Myb0cJKcExI4@WTTcd1TCHOP5JAQRfyukOcQRm@PljLYnMcWR4MGg4ZUTQWZoAEnQYidiJLOr6GxitAx4OrPGAQd5ZXF2z@NlEssrbzoaSQhBV2Af2iarUwdQ7Wgzx1/4iQMRtWfmYoXZKVr3GjHdPALKzmm9lZtU01Hng8KWC6xfdydBs7EDm1O05FhcGKSZ9l9wfsizmdK7MHeSPLmovzLfJA/ALECOfKHUIIbmenC7bPMZjxJpZ5ceDI4fkPfR1B4zvi@@FkbWVWelVM4@JgS8p1PhrxYRnaoIdMemDAjquT5DxD6I3sA@C1v7SWy4sVG6runWbP1w8WkvZm6mPx68YtJmMglWe2yabEhD7PViiXnCuyMWSv0U3mleUACzJ0oLibhAhcTcuvi03tJAkAkm2r9kG3/mgWELjZMczN7scEECQ0ZYpK9v70sgs@uoLkRxiK7YTwxN001@Knv8qaAvZX@4hjyC5P/AhZKqSQzPeg5sz6AohgguqUAFbvsq@3cznZ@BzShgbNIz5xr3G/T3vWlswBRwkN1Fraei19C3BAixN3Cs/fh5QL6ORxMMCE0jagnE1rIJVROc2rH8NkK6mSYJ6A8UDmFJMAQF9MvY@PhIyr8lgCWU2UpowW7Dmrcl8L903PH2I7t4boWjQ5hjkQvA/YRIRNqGiFLxlvLoaaaLkkKNsuI4ysHBhmBwPBmN7TdYuJO0lJYMzPJfRSiMWpmhHl9o3N0ZYqGZugzKUwln4r84Xcv//t/137emG8cbmc/zODvfOPnjb1XG/wID/Drhfp1s3G4cYDF9u42llnQgeHx5X//H6h/@HeAg1@WB/DP4a6CtbfcOEwXqcqvG4d78JDf3oZ2/@9//Rf04RlrbJjZ5lnHEoTYvqLIsT0h3oXvooq9ZLU0GSwreVxYEAZ7GIJuDj/QMWqx/SpHZroN6VVxg@4/w/7c90eRWzw5Zs3JVYgtGcqfAiQjrlDEBtIMUrlQ9IXmu6HcNpB5AzTFP59n9jzQAP4p3Tn8Jn3Xjeceugw9Y7UIBjDFLYI@zw@Hue8SvntHIaF8SvaVCImqnVxrX73YB3Z45zrzYTfsJaGm67hr3zqXGeTDjNO7Bp1q4o3cH2fZG2DJcX77VbaPxv0s@XFnpwQpPV1mfgFBUGYjAcWQnE4tMYMRcMfwF54xRwkI9Cf@mZTKzgFS9tTpsg0rnOEJijSa5Uq9bvHxMHYnE4jSKfoXBHjMQyLTamiR5xcTqFmrF0Riyy/I5UjnNRGbd@QcK5OOpNkblrLXggBDfUDroOpPpjQbUBAS1ZoBBC6SsXu9ji2/pYwnCRV4bhlPrpzRtJgg3zDoDd6vBhK6pD@LmWuhpIdoQUinaaFDWGNnboOKXkzQG9THgxbmeE8Bn7WSbkyri0/Wviwrtfpe8QTPtO5p@pabvoURRSkhaMfnmSAXzkToxXhtKaKpcuZ08EgttmFozVMpsGYZ@oMYeDws1T6GJcjuUAQkUC3ojvQq04fNIl0YeOTW4Zg9Ni1yHjBjIwh@tFQJ4KzqWQZlJ2w3w43BAnHmTpwCeijzPXgYAVFUSVuGExKAVj6r2GEJhvpQmzqMpiIUdsSS29IE9kMSODCWUgAJho7Hm1rgg23w7uGDlnC0hD4JNLwkTGSpfoGULSqohqNASbW4cdTM2E7V6go/WU9f5gKiG97wRSKX336xs7v38tW3GDP@RPY2HgxWyqAWML2yAQZJ1ClQsvF9sZhIJvgVJvRabRKhx4HFAzh067o1CSt@fFrM5ySwXIJg3VJiKq4uzZUEMoA4czK4I4COkpolUqnvCi3sWPuiZ/4K/yUsVZsZDk3N9mj4i82k18bhHQdEUJqjsTN2Z3g8jguzTZldMKc@bCH8RS/ruP26g7dXoa8rsz00dOq6GJQwc68HVzp3ZNjaL5owYYDg89myQBrUa4cjRUmn1rBCWVQaHKpa9EVRwWut9gCdcnFLQJmPgcM0g8mAXv629DTF2ZGETQjzPGDEKh4haq6jOjsTd05cUTkrRxGTmdCGng83o3u2gnAH@yGAr9ROMPOR1t0mUBemxED2Wq1JFhv0SfeVC1wOywFXINNjrHQX03ppVFFrNckN89R9ZMkTLw79hHZBVRhHxCsGZj73MClVXKvqBRJELYTSmuQvYpZ/nqOTLMBJH2Scp8jLiYLmI/p26HmUy1s2ljClRykVgoH0@FQiDiDabXIJ7kiugCNKjxVKY8Wjzde@kssk3pTKA@xrqk5syWFfmgooapwzi/i0wP5Xz44tUa7APycfyhYKykelf2C//YRZ6/HNS3zzBVE9UUNABJVmOPK5RZ@pnzFECZglZ3H6kgBBXHzJsIH1SPJGClaqJ5L2PKlbobndDrgC2dWWQriyjspJgllTyAbyRCrvZDqTuRalQl9g49XqSrMlC6tpwSau@ye2RpMnQas@JCblI0BsR0GkFYiA258EDM8e6CR521J3UYxdPYnn6RDLskIFYvtJFsge5tm1lLmPLbYlW2wXcBzv4wvi23t5g28wCzPHA7zx9Mt4I/145kj/WzBH5c/hjheSO14UcO1h7ph0Zw6tSBTRSUnt3BiOuVzSHtzpDQdDtA/1tZ/YiZylAaAFjy4msykeJJ/Dvq1ZTkQq/sNWdD9CJ6Ht3T3jCzu/Izu/U8A1lx7Lzv/Uzqd/487vys7vFnCviRl5KdrJ8NffrseBSJgKv4gdXhR3uZj5pT3dkz3dK@BuGjPMf3hP079TT1/Knr4sYMYEPnDgFK73czNLIqXGcbUauFtkVAbiFGYFjOdKE3UvvBzbEv3RtXdVRGldfDH@ryT@r3A1oqc6ktXWYpR9XZ7VUw6WZ8mSr8/DICvuCfdXhnrp/ZUbVqCPyA2KF2kybM2kogICucUfg9OmTCA/Bquvv/k8Fmde2ym3EmeG1RRo1gjzZjDFWfKlwioB6xNm5Dla0o6b9dOt/8VkGNs/ySg0QB6H9hbvGJI7ia6C4Vjxa9kZrTsIuyF1jhCrSHISsnMZ7e2zy5P1qxoltojsi/FKAh@1cbpkzEDlaB5AZDIC2mRkfaVVoWuuUi/4DfSdC8V3Wfb4i7j0W8ml3xZEXSoG60hlS4Of5MVAT9ve3b1vD@BaGfyDEzBnQfl7ZtX/Cw4XVt0/Sn2kTuet43kbWrIoQ8/TzWUElhHhMqVrKDMr4HUxk0v0P3jvJ5/aNrRsy6CseIZx/LbcQNuFfdntOf3B1fDHn8YTd/rzzJtf39wulr/kE4ahkvOnTM5aqLxvpJliNV9zYpaIJG1Oa1mbAxBomE@y1SRsCEnm80mzVShst02B83PM@Zj4fCAAQCLqxBvhHUnkZuFnD6ehZA@GaGyvR0f/3hxjzoFkqZE9vuzZYlEQ6H@dzlsCvcHk2y4QEkhEdphUF1bPqWmadCeMvHIiqUMuJC39p97V2WBcZfucSCQkSvCzSgcCaGzxi/oWmhaZXNpiE5iPvwx7YUsJ22T8mjK1HqoFkk@3d9pmAcj0gb4gw1/ZozmfCKZ@MX1PGGfuRxLg1nnMixzuIjkzFLigIX1AG6DfMVMyR3DKxf3V1tXQd60dH0YrAN8OFQ7RSvuxBVPfD90BYDAV3CPXHZ3i@KoWLEkNS7wKOhNkQsSw5jf2qO@PgspWPGSnyhDvhPtIOWSR2qGBiRBCEqPvr3RBMPUVNutKS7FfHw8bAONLcldYAaXji5VWCqxwCa2hoZw@tGlE6/HwenNOJx7TiYA5Wz4SlCM64Dft/Yb4vlaH0b@xZ0M0bLG1LQ9tZJwMzM8BOfzP5WSKTVQkJ9f2LswrHzLNMHMFufg@rUM5tfoS9F75EhugdQc7gFfoqi7gbjag7IYPI/0IlO@ZziEOZbDI3iewHfnsrZg6vyeFumQSkZbyY9y0C3M3svYMfYxTryKDreiA02sPyaVetFleCT6/wnHGnGOwB8xsdifbEOfzISziy8CnmYQbchjTpSxKQsTAODd/dAJ3ryxxKX/I/DoSU23xQNpQnv4rM0g0vqZzCliL3TG2xEs8cyeG8CGCAIczIG/GrYjYmP8zK7bN9d2FUthPb1WwjHQ5NKjx3XWvdQRyD/YzKK@eYA/R1/EVQgzbYRZYhaCWWuk6jHuD/LTK2Xgk1elg7p9Oh1KtdDooP3Q6SW6FhQlNCNLuvShd9q5n6Zl9Nbbtyd@zXc9L4/Xb07lhdIGsBwciWTkrJzHUyv@UmS5hHNKbaSHz9AsSOfCNkUiEo0yPGw3ROK5X3zUFfTNoTLruaORI8UDKSLVZD@8HLQ@7cyU2sZSnfo1tTCtk0IWU4tjzGoQL9xAHt9NB9/9OJ@U5o742OhvBE/z3pvn2VDQp4WCz0qB8iI2YoggjgwGQpJ4i4gdPy7Xj5sd3FaDieHRoHKg/UOiQ6h3Mh/ORc3iQ5b/8zpsvURRYTh3QAuW7LL2EulmufHDp9pbwpze8EfSpmFBH/4WZA@LW8MbZh8o6bQnBvuvOAwSzUB@BSmhZRlBV0CuDIFcr10RB2D08sgFBUCkPOKk8DAwZ9pci@SKZGXqk16fMcMvy5hMpjSb5ZwZbTFoiebuVjNn6wwPReFMCWr4@rR2VTjHj17tKHdNYrhuLy0EHmAYlWLqWIRn@yuFp7iQkVNCXuZRYox/Dpb4n0Tj87mP43Zpu1Cuvq5jPcT3mTNKi@JQr5O/Cn27Qpyr2C11CQd/uVjFYg8rJaen1vVigUrey79FXtDDHfl3TVO3sdQ1TUGLqzHUtupMBaBqDDrYcQ171GZvu4EUd3qPorVo@qpXvoflgxJ2JNoqN4fR4VFPHtfOz9YuDdBHOh6FsGD6i5813500jXNNfrGDC0DpliYW2VGlTS/qkLMx18I9KjYqonFLGU@0T@bqMnLGCbomlxYsKqKC0djoeiC6WSlSIYkwhGtdM16rGLkf2JejP13NnH@NAC5/upov9uTuVDzjVMMdvgWNdU5/ues7A3L8wPt0luO1iAhg6cfjpjheri0mSr6KZpySi@mRewdtH2jQixChX6tX3lbKiR0P7HCoJRKseq68@vbrDWRfj5jSKUf4ZS2afiRmh1MomTF@I8gwhSSCYMgyGn9HvajBDr9o0TXJ4u3/p4uYHu3BveO0VdnPP9326SERWmmOQlr44RpKux8gJqsPoXfYndvc36xz1BWHX7@0QiLWglV6OMHEF/Df63Tt4YcgRvXTnc3ecprTWani5Vug7TqbQZx8ATK71tfFjTNVoT76E3CskexRvqWlGqZ1Pqse8yTdA6i/V67UPjchquMKX9mzm3p5Pfx/WFDk1bvAkKUirmEC6CVjXhj1xYdAqRhfYzf15ybW0YjGFeChlqQuDy@nMjroEYWJmt@kiwuDXV01mIlrZvZ38S5INd4/flWZhOtWx0h9HqKB399ApxDlrCaXR/A/nrlNo@1@SaDoL/k5UW7/mUcr2e9e8QIBpVr5vRoUWJD/dS61THl98GcFXt1@9a4FASC2sYQ@Jr492vPp2zwrfH45G6wRfX8VbrMrLUqJcU1NT/xbr5OV6pVE7fV8R5erralO8L52eVyJi8wzPhm4cPsiWTc2cAV4IAfSjEyqt4aSmQHQxtILi4Pgci4Ld8DQcbUZ936Bpib7D4SDDedLjsoZuUfXz/UzciRPbkmoi0MsLcSmeoqChWvLXJFqv6Eu4zi3eDlqUcOWB0K9JM2p6h2LSrSeJhhkOliBvW7xuFe@xXDUIj6QNjUcpRN@Asgg43zZXF6Grx9bejqstSRE5KgSJ5sqMmOfDnfNAsVvt3PZq54BgX9U9iSDatTLQaArg3Y9Z1/X@cMSgzYcRA63wj6YaRrWEKGdGdPnVEwpyQVjHJbLhFs2C8GmYDHr7h7OkSKq1MM7UpF1ZUWBZe3A9ecwU1c9Rg4PUxVNU4q2VCWw@NIWP3dHqkOXX9i85G1yCTm/R/5v@LhJ7Fm/dd8lF/PG9teZU/z5A5j3DHbsURjaF6lm58q5yhlfSiH9UPn6o1ctoEm5EtwZ58XtkCH1PbDKherrNWTewqgpcjLJRzF11TxTIMVdi5HZhVuBIkLGMduJFcNTI4Dn4BR7kzcuhk2J1EE/LBJkzkmFqrMBgNhGr6zwdM3OHENzOKj9QJs37Ji9Xx@spVuouH1k3H1MX89M/tu3tNfUf2/6LuPpkmWVjkbRXIUb8Z7lGiPbXS32I0ACzboDun@Qrw2f@vgMo/v1GkKxfXzl@yuj0Rw3iq78G0f@/y9kjK@/EVR49svJuTOX5Y1vei6v82JZfrmVc39S5yr2WiFrsPoOdpd3trxXpT1qRlN3zvkUpftDQ7vfXsP2Zw0aW188fODJE/jVyf@bIsS3484cOraF/jdyfOXJkj/46CQ4NkZFBJANpFD9U3aPYhdth9wq0axKA8Mf7REi0aEZQCKyZTuoRZDIf2xiqk1@mEH6prveljMZOO2j1lmZroTzWJWMV2ut6HfbeeF86FW9r5epJnAfHCoE85w@b0tuk6PtkCyy5@JG8b@KMZrMOm5YfTVURCwSdBP0xx/D@2EmGfkktVbxNtmHZfoyrNfvL@vXMR/g@S8/d25mL8ece3rCkQrzH9lzjQN@OUirjpcqntfM6DGy98RkTvef@PgPrTtfSkU2cX8L9N@ygr9bAKCf5iytP6mjPZCnEDD5vJeMdtDVTJ8XS9EeuHaBGbzHJPb9eMf2G20h/TRvpx7Wx@TVtbD6ujezXtJHNxjWyZlkqV47OX4usaLypfYgvQ1@8K7wgCm936s4cZ7JuCQuvYVDn9@H1WMv5n2YFjOwQ/mj4syNS6UH7vVyOfgLpxL/HQl@EtMHh4ePRGU5UCuVHDQ9dgPYHjs/n7BdxY8RU4WOK35Sea2zxZ7WzNBngQ4Z4vsPe92zVTfKeh0kCpVXec69nXf08hVLT4hjxlyAzbWolcureHQxvUwo70HKID8Z5qXwPFPoqVCZRvhsknm/ZMXULBjy2kcAP92sa8b1cV9oJLUxKPCHuvJjEbybxfY9dLANv59aKA3C7lUSMkm3FkESIWDAbOqB0Oo1VPiWZUZOFT3cgExIoeLxbj0eMB3AsrrFezysl1/syr/J90Ly5lqAr4xwLLxJy4gNfdZ0218SP@RNB5mgOsYc8R6LLI/SLJAr3HrktQqmcw7VF0tIjedaSk4/TAlnTEgtYgvDfuAX/0S7jsRPhcQMc7xiuXVNGlwkba@cRLfcjdbi6ETOXYmGEq8VJbHjyCwSPp/aazVHj65VgROIIqQXwGfvKceJ9nE9V49j6gVP/yPrQV4pFMLHx9Nyf2snk3Zq1gecY1fcvT0CqWEB0My5OUcftcB1qhARpO56kC@iZ60tiIS1eKWWunb5TyjoXQF8/t@ROPEWqnLkT5wtIyH8fJGIMB4YnsO9vYq/YSDSljI@2SaxIk1hBAUT@GTdlJyRUv5anw@y6Dh3WEUuiXimVRaNZFyfnZ8eietZo4ovaCX04rZ5VYk51lvHDom9/iuAtRe12kPrx0StvGBBviP9KqzBp84rgcuylpxsxuz/2D3D5A3OMaB@K1oqjLIqX8YRVI1R4mAbxFVsAux0o4sP2vYCGnBPj34AL4qlxP188qA1oGsHEFd41JvXCzcRZgA7iJc3HrlGtwg4vS7hX/0Y7pSYgxO6U68WOmMUoTlpeY89TV2J8xsAxCek@@BjZQqqZ6pYMY@28owL5NXa/wM1JLghRD6fQ8ET0t9IRrLql42alLN5Wmm9q5Yb/KeLMi3G60Sjd1dA3LQTXjATnJy@dwfUkGmNKoW@T3iMhc@xsbFhrhnI1xYe8ZrojF2i0ghHd/p5cG613XDo9LR2dViRpogF7C6cr9VjM@duZ2vOraA9YjVURt34x2O1nyUj2l1fJKHo6hEi3aDAi70K6tawXKYKENo2HIs85XhyQ9uO1ZVNBYhytXIbpEKS2MQ3MLGoYyAUi3RXpvB6Q/lSLOqbrdGTadH5tYXqkiXNLU832k9Ia/xMCuR8ZXpmT0ZW5uODKHMVWslM/hUTvBzGWicOd3K6MB38oLpxJLFMdhYP8xdQdLQcjF57hASie7Tk32cn1aGTglt8b9vvhQdCfD7/Zxhsxne6VKwCb/w8)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/ib5vn)

I now use `len(dir(os)+dir(1))` to separate Python 2.3.0 - 3.11.0 instead of `try`ing to `import` various modules. All Pythons are supposed to run on Linux now.

```
 ver     #      len(dir(os))  len(dir(1))      sum
2.3.0    435        202           53           255
2.4.0    436        206           53           259
2.5.0    437        211           54           265
2.6.0    438        218           63           281
2.7.0    5          224           64           288
3.0.0    1          216           66           282
3.1.0    425        217           66           283
3.2.0    426        232           68           300
3.3.0    427        320           69           389
3.4.0    428        329           69           398
3.5.0    429        331           69           400
3.6.0    430        339           70           409
3.7.0    431        344           70           414
3.8.0    432        368           71           439
3.9.0    433        375           71           446
3.10.0   442        387           72           459
3.11.0   434        387           73           460
```

`dir(1)` is needed to separate 3.10.0 and 3.11.0. Python 2.7.0 cannot be tested on TIO now, `len(dir(os))` is different in 2.7.16.

The code:

```py
import os
print({5:12,1:11,11:13,27:14,34:-419,28:-423,29:1,46:2,135:3,144:4,146:5,155:6,160:7,185:8,192:9,205:18,206:10}[len(dir(os)+dir(1))-254]+424)
```

I could not find a minimal enough perfect hash.

Moved `a=9;p=2;` before `import` to fix Chip.
`print` [doesn't work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKugKDOvRMNAkyu/WC8@tSITxP7/HwA) on TIO if `os._exit` is used, so still using `sys.exit`.

I didn't want to fix ><> again, so I've kept redundant CRs. Keeping them in Python
code creates various problems with SNUSPi, psPILOT and css-script, so I've put them on line 51. Spaces are for CCBI Befunge-98 (huh? weird).

Answer (score 1):

## 445. Ruby 3.0.0, 18905 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPZdSD4UdHp@RGXCVYBIJBvvEGAZLFYXWzVSySru90ACpVIJIBsJjJRmQkSKJIV3RqHVm3JHluWbFmW3bK8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsanm84djYBDLzPs@999xzzz3nvrKj@4Of/SyBF3ni2tO@7QYkMP2AdD3rxPREcmdKtnXLz6sax2GoHa8/HppO4Fe4BFEIsXWnP9b7JulZdmB6WeKbJumYtnsK/iohm2Nn7JvdOtg0QhzzlOw7htUFCCRwj03Heml64Jcj5K5pnw/PA2K4w6HudH0y8iwnoL55Qp7oYOmNjWOid/zA043Ach3wKiwkUVywlQh56Hq@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@lDwEbXpDh9d/8J8Q3XAxvcGJY1rJvAGHpANjdJcu/R3SSpx9Uieh0urqIaOYMqSESe5ES3x0Ah8zXhQv14cWwOqyy5lqyQJKBFlUkuR3LQfktEzQOSFLkMBmAEqqbAXSBqieQUaG95okFgTYXGXQAfaBAkJ4NjOZnF9Hue3rdsk0HvI/QiNh@IpsJTzhENWoZW0Fjovmv3WFCDZqRItBIpFEkxT4rwLJOyCjnBZHPQaPJwF@AGiGXIJgBSNci0rDJgs3YBdIy0uEt6@tCyp2EKNAmD5BVSBKhQHgWgqyWAAm9Nw1uDu4TQFq952MEAamOgnwB4wbaOkZ2ZMUfDKpbgJW1sSJR1Im9myfsDTB5QC0jNl0gRki8ARnKQBcC8WoLkwVPLQxYghJYvQME0uAuscP7AtO0Q1MBHULQERRluKE0R8FOCGoOaUGVEdBFusANHVYF1qsAnVWB9KrArVQWzhslCOKzCAlR/IceSGej@MSTE0lG7tFKgOwAwCtYCskkFEQcQoCYJoF/DjJKchsQDmYcyQV6KBQKEUVJIKUdKRQI4LssE6kyBfCFlKcChFciPgsCANhQgDgXypEANKABU0fKEm6sARUN/iKtBXECXkoM4OTBDZSoFvCEeUIwCSSqQpqqWZ4QLeVPzUN68RilaLUCNF8EP8KZCXlUgMyRjtQT@GLcEOCwhwReTWYYIHfEANYVNBOgTkAHVo1C4EBbMajEkaN0eDfQO9gcsZqeHUQvYdAqIRogqY/HgnUNsQlagllVsIZB9FahCoy0M3rk4eVsBIA0Eb3YtytRt7FiUGEPFLCXSD/VRMEObUqA5Gk2DQeymMjcXmK0FDNPs68Y09oSWmY09Z64FDV1Vyp9ngOQcuvrAjd2xb8@AxIacSpMyTyx75laibl1T7/Ysf/BqltccTaRj6oFjHc9Syeezc0jV5zwK6LHgVNTmwwaWAF1cf4CmWVnUIoYZuXEFLWRZUWj2OmZv7PRNoVyayx/1CcZeAJ3RLM0yc/asfh869hkcJUuLSTvXmXOe5tDWNOjzI0fELqbpWdDl3ybGAESW2LPM4JfLMxiaijCmegclAQFEOOg5ytjX9awJ6dw2aE8zy6BG8WQMrFEUuLIy8Fzl0kQmpcIcbVDMvSzJMcvGqyV@6FpOKkmSae6Cg/6JiaXzvTt0gu9hz4Z9NZIu9MUulTRmLDXlRL1pGpC2KBhAT22jANUxDR17bezDTNoHR3CsQCSQCMiWpnuCMi/tSBeS8Wln2/FQxAXJqGt6HsGwIBf7Wdot@@OOb74Yo@w1y1cP@nkTxIGebtlxBmjfogdUaIB30of0povZ7nnukHZAQ@x2bdcdrRBxoJM/RUD33VNzlvWZDKCPRjZIWuBuMkEPMnOqU2GdSvbzqbIMQSSMBxUOAGlSIKFYnmlQ3IdFh9gayDKLWawQtX5bQyh35kQwDRoLiCc@xnHGtl0B2cg0iFaXuuaJhC5MTFsUzzAPkeAG4lcIoqODNI45p7mIId1WRSoSHkU167vDxaKxPnc/LvrAQmHKPtWnUHs96G7NiT4EnYGgYA4tlwyBYlgNYk2AcoHF2idd10kGMZRTDwRfKHRcEipcI04Ca2iC6uRCFKzxHM009vg0Z50pkDLFVk6kuhLLyRVEidxVRDGH3JwDaywgInbHBmIN07YcSkEgQvmoF3jAKpkbF3ik2dTh9kAGHIXqoYgGDHiIWZvTMnzW2kNp3aAQUa41HR8UF18kFipvQPl9twfEdmpB2YFhQdQZbIMiAVEQO01EQ@QoypGAhsc2sYgxGhFwh04JyPOeXAKx1f3QIi/B0x6A2mGMPW9KJiOoCWsIoQLD7fWAel@aowGAIMMuMaYGNE@oZEo9/sDRR1zXpWzGGC0WdmZbNyGMg@rM7pNfJH0TkA@ibg@VSST8WTFGI1oQihDdYWKwowO@sCDGaEqRwyVmMXquK6J71zV9SjKudxwzAEzMN/u0gUBr681Y0hDFeqBVh6ojXeA/YSND@Jggt7QwmFRIC2@bDjQgA2gTmj5UItbsDumBnj4n3KKGohuGOQpCanEpU7OcOU3h8T3UFKirEAIT/QG3vk02r9AOBI3pZ07KRc0Jsz4KFRgdOW44GCBQ8SNWVhl/safXkocQJ1dS559jmIUcPOdX5GFEGwaqTZRVjANkKMgjLWOAHDFAnkMlcWhz3vh68cFtPnlvSIRenDbmRgHmw4lS7IT5WA1DgNu@Dkgc2QirvuCAQRccXgNa94dLILtxJu3uvKso6SKwxtcBHbqOuwQqIDOGi0EWfWhdUGI8RN6h2zEx0ubiL9QRsu3Z@BR2Z9CTjkauBy2DsZ4pHYOgVTZHXaHqnop7jLRI7ix2sNBxJLHbD7AvhAgjWwdawCaGLRV0Lh34BbAyploD53NZinMZpq2ewgrzd0o7AEZM0KM6jolqm@5NGRAoHnTSkNCUWJ4HzPAEuwrWE0VdikjpFHoGvdtF/orooO3@auIiUvTuuGNNrurvBjqKH/rcie6RHqruHoge0IhSyZ6fTFepO40558VL7iiQaFT25CEgDSRClad6vohdxT1gNIdTx0jxC02MzxJ@HPRKfBoMGJFJauQdUBiu5g6VCCSa4TG0a2qrkj504oIATwHdaE7QQxLRQ/dA2oBGCLpmudzt6OQcuIdHhMkuU0gixUQRc3FaptON0woRgXmZL6/IkvA9gxqEub4NS4DBaclpJ7GAwDfEBI3Ig4MkhT0sOlCZj/lR6YY5jh063kdSTCBJk7NYBIYOIEUzY4EIYhlW0A6Fltu3I/FlrVYDYgOZCthmNz2v10ZjoSJwaggsUpkkTEQM3MMA20YqDeXFwBcsNyA8AaXW6uQsGHjQ4qj9goNAgFbOQUqOEBvW8yPreNy9WtEOOmIgHlsdiE6WEfBVDkQA1hpqN2E1uYBV0H2TiFUkXoxPQV8jXuqKFcqHwTzTRyG4FmZlroZTmIOQVpeiiEUN3WYEvTs17FAkYCZo7IwbdSD7x@EQWMyIsqFMEDXaay2VAcHmwOCQJztH92thW2SeUsdyKgsOtmvoNnVex@B8FPfB/p2DnYNfbC@BYVudylUHycqVCtjVjidC3xlLOVGtrM/DmAG@274ZNkZcDMNzoTcR3MmcqDQ1oHOZROh8fPDFqygBSQjRQVMAM95XRBoWBoQurqP7gyudMOlnMpBkHCUKS4R9EsGMDZh19Nej/DwZv3yJlXc1U6PQHXNmj3UGIHKU9p0onoieVwSwyKvTYz0ijQuyqOXg/MbMNB8yys/bKDtfzQwVqOdI5u3H9/YOahRsOLom0CCSH4AspXtdEWjeHoMiviwMsD8wGSQjzjKOUjXN61IEG8YCgmd1S1bABwCo8YguEexhVDR/AHnfvVo26ioYMQVQO4VwVa6cl4eMz5vRuXxgF2eg4rusF6Ues84qdlraY8W@i92Wkc@bxVx5vtsyZml254HS6QToByK50QOvY19AF3EmRYZidZj9wwfXMu5TIRJUASHKmW8Tkabl2xxqL4JFkr60C3qaa5vie5Tj8YRPS1IymlEQDZ@qoHPh9yZWkJLT7K2kISykvrOzr96NAoeD2XQ8gyoNqJFjz@T1cIrQ8IFGHNd2@y7ZgDhMOowSBLFpZTF3@q5zrYZ0dMSiJnCWEfgvDt/oI@hrrJdUfaSx5pVWNl@pO/4pcGmloCGSKIYoKImGFz/UT3RA16zch/sf7EEnouRlOTbL9AIUzMWh6EKTMedKHYgACYlhfpYWMJ6WvNbaIw9hbl4QCx0yujjizsx7qSPlmKK0NPzSLL3jXsP4h@70CmmBCyMtMMyhbP/Rkwf7j/Ye7rzfDNR8fsGek8sFQByk1wFZSBwwvGFr3WBNE4uF4BLQNjxsXsAFxqCgRPNMY98Dxi1iEJFlYAXVsAnd1DvuwEn66auFOUVf4UPHYCT0EBsfCxpGBEW7a6My4rEJb@zPkX4GQTDyK5IErXww7oigtEofGq6t9yUaDzoG25YUVF32H@Pohr8sBmTGn5osBhviAtFhSscRdXvogvJCp82RNZAUA0/HrmyrPwBdGOfWTS8txhRMSyN1QUMAXVmKy0YZMLUBbsN3VE88I@23FLXE6FqR1ZzER8EWmj@EXeuZoDqloLcCVKSvWEnzdvM2mQKXRkhXgSSIuEEHOXyCfYFNQJCkY6eo50fIodwCR02RV1AcvRjjmC5wKSkv54pKIS@BWgZqGsisAo68CUM9MAZC4AoAT3B7dNxgjgp7vqE7PXEjNESZBbnvFhRVazxrNp0WCOjN2zRvOGPdmLYaSitdJdejbITh01Wg3oXiIe1GDkC71AikSd9kBT/r6tfZWVenratLpGA4CvscYUQe7oAg9dIFft0159seRpDmPaWNhbASBn4lLRkQsjEqhw/ElAQNCnpaID0J8yWA0IviIVAO8K25CGQ2mhELTNNgAPxDI6ldakpfl3DRWQu5xmJWcGhYHE2B5dFAyLQFDTMUedAERwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwlHHrD0EVQTG9DahY4A1DkfhyID7IJxzmbMxoaxSYZWHPDcET4guvDyJuEiCg2AL3/4WS@EE4ttIrmjI8UBFq5IdmFEkTxFFgB9@ZQEdKSha6Iaj8smnjoWKiIiR30F6LqS620x8NYID2ld/vBPLz/@7uXXP778@FuXH//65ad/fPnpv1sTXqGOWd/MNJuCmG20CJ@8lvlbe@qtnTu37pRoDkGehMz/X7/063/3G7@ymPcl6f74o6/9@KNf/ttf@fhvPvvoxx99@Sc/@vpPfvTVn/zokzdK1/k/f9U1/uvHbpjkKQ6NzCcYpgfJDQbQi94Hqa2xcev0jKytrUH0tbUtqIm1rS2SIVvwFOC5Bv3mFvhm4blFGuC7RlrkosWBBuuTJaN9Ih0/F03dGLSBWxpmSkuL0OWdnU/OyWDQmIjQzo95Y4NvXdDZJdoX4IwLy/QuVtohXTmDeX8Hum9mm2V@VdINqdmQm63mWarZzaSbF1JWaYGW3bbw4afUdEMRRQHckLekJPGsdCHFeZvQkBBINAbeLGd0wo4t5EFdmhH8PWsCPRGwSiCk@TF5ylro5A4OrX5gjgZTbz5APF4F8imOPc/Wh@AyGuR/8/zlJYs/Lwot6MiRxMjCgViIw14oaYymjC9yLKdNaWF5UtRjnQi9oRvo0rsiqBviXEeTXEtKggB9CPVhkGixH1q@AaqF7pju2J8fo1s6dIipg@vRYAzse3dgjTjTGLhA6dsAk8SzJIhknPAR2LRRFK1riHBjs0aWgVMM0BvTpTsWVD5tvXQUQ6FJn@i21Y3HsvOF0QsxTq1K4xAZE7L6juuZAiACYnB0nRJdBsfVo9ncfTpSdI1Xhr60C0C@a5lBltyzXZ1i1HWAFuaoEedCZvFBn4UoB2aXsx0i9EC0EFkNeGZX2uDo3KbrDYBdQmlwykaN62gYekiuP@qKwQSicinsoOY9mTYEQtop6aqqWjDyvUrkh7QAyB5A1aAW54BKGHkJCnimw6rdY8MokU776PHdPTbWQDsn7I5w3Kk9dLtjkMNCPePAdPpZsgdUZDnuEFipE8V/eWwfuG7AtGKwrBrJYEqmNRzbOh0juTqMcWM8w@24Nh06uSnqLPzY83VbZ4M2ke/Ouw9BNn56dFgTK3OBJP1keGPaOG63PFmGz/35mTo6SxlNp/iMMPn1PI/dXLTQEplL6FFCjyEupQRZMdSiqTV2DAOeKfIFhl2pbsThFBqOyUizhM4UlbqfBL3egrNGnY8F5CX2zDlHndnyygV1yOvMAuVZIFxruRBmHlCBhomXXK4MV6Th2HIOINaZR4l66HQBpoBD9wu@Zeo7W4GJ0k/IweIJ@4FpRxNwB@bQxUkm6CVtnM0A0R4FWbZG0oS@YoRzCZRN4wwVdAk6RLwqaEETGwksNJdYo82mYzkSThRx6xIJR4irtOGA1s1m9nzGQl3QjOngw2adzQij5uExpUdiY9frbQCxWa9GC9ZWBcOUksk4GIVK8wYxaDHpJPi1osZLGnw6JM3RKFXOl0Donqiy0JwU91rnScmnaOgRvtmc3JLV90EmwdWI67elvlml64FW4Ksa@SQpww77co6GYsO7xgC4C8lMFlEJ9TN2eq7dFdhcEtAaYVoIVlA4oR@vkgwXw5qWFy2QpCtUWVTkqnNrK6/BvVKl9esB5lZjxoBQfCDnx9mTc9I4zpIT0R/ZVgAiEsoTg3BVkXN13Sadz9I9T5/6XLgepEZ2Dt5@tyG3GARuqOP8UInV4iRa/gtam@eOccE2mHBVS2AFtNens/YWlheEHIhApxIg@wCDJVAlcUJhiajkY57PytIzQZ9LmVRcmg6zxExfiD1bDwLTYTTHJulWo5vNpoTJ1GjyW@HQfIXIdP7C6kEuwQ@yWCWHR3f3Dg5EFOhSyT2c56hAcwTREYSRVYWOMDlf@Aq51U2SWxgnjcotB00N1PV2GB@IugpEPzZxNgfZTt/0UuCYxikKA5zprBCNyKSxEEG4NskIKI5iYClQtrcYsMrS/D91jh33NK7xClB8hmIS0J26XUEpMy2OHeuF6EP3QgVNCBLqU9BL1NZTlJOtK@lw8dkQJ1hBqKYCIpSg0SCgM/HrEJgnrVaVzZRDWPADN8Quz9OqoKvEa0pU9TVwBkGGQgij116RZw1ZKLcy68tA0YVY4QJvVv45uAhhEbRvLk12PUXb@7WGzPLAZswY937q0@WPi9scKmSdGXg2MkuDR4uLKNOha5EW1xQtrliCRoashA5YYEEilpAIl9@HNEv9KecHrRejUYdUmpzFSFcR5eT8nOKQrKuE4hBMCmGVcRFpxcCYHrhQmgfh0vt5mYC21nC5BbbZJsdXYm1elEWZRycmp0snV4RR4YT6Rpo5EwYt59il0yGxqS2LSh4FwDj28Ni@HhNXatLHQlA6mbqQLVUszmfLH3Z69LEkDp0OCCeaqQMdaA5lXhAWdemAvuiY8/XoVxZXRM5Mv2eLN2nfCmYivHhNSKFcooF7nY61KiiUHldNRe@lWDhAClbFnKjMinh1/Q1ZQGy4mjR8/7ePuoDg6@gfQBeAI2@xoQ2dMlaFsAyzC1HRQh/La44NEI9tS6cIoKbXgTR0D4qk27FhOWg6CS0I0LEPcUg9rFkgPnyAKLkyGTXMOZsRi97LE1k2qeQAMzRWhb2yHoklRac/QFHrUiQw8cYyaSTKlFglmBM2BTGnKCODen2mokVDhBItq/fBOBizJ0izr61Ea4T3chQshJTzekcxJbZ@@4Yq9/TjcdcVRsf9WAItLAk7Kz0dHxKgow@nQ9toXF58VkC2Hjp6rwo267SkU/p6HVX4ztgfCR2qVXeZjTaE4Q0peDZ7rgpihfvfYsNqrFk2fbwhJYbQgVDC1QASrrgU5pBmXUGzrXemKF0MPj@VxTPrwHFqRiYjayumVkej1fFRk6Txy@XlsSeiwfCxTOeX2KrOUKWiBQ7Xeb6mVqE/soa6LajdOeNKpr1sYv5a0HhOj8bBLQh0H8KNRI4djzG2dW9muoHErw0jXxuQjjpHy3Chgx8RpSgq6ow5RovAZiBx@Sx9zE30W8sQFm2fEGLT8sbuGgEujlxBPW/AutiiRFz6OUcOorsKJ4Z7ivcqb38A6iV7Lu@7Xi7N1RuwIcE2bB165pWMf2FYD4cNX0OSp5Zv0sdyxB4vzWhg2EvdF4k9GrCbH4B7HQH7lu365JA@b0JQ3wMssOdy0p3HpaU7Ah28njffwG2i2fxZhep237ULpb6kw2NlrY@9HnL48P2mvCzmRYryGl4UCTquo4TvlRz8WPKOX1dBdNOehys554w3dKbLGFI4W7G6dCDc406F5SW7J5doTFFig3orEsb1K6f6NHr/HJ3EKtRGncRoSgVkkOMwQrkEhsBjQvPPk1ru5tS6b8aUroEtvq4Qc5V7bJvQLdHntSolqqx8zhiKLL85i@rZY3NsLlUdHnc@NMMO480Tl8Psrodj6Th8j1su4lAvQ2XujXKHPS/abmQaOk7XvV44WWReI5CnR6jmPgHDEzRcj9F3xqOF2lvQq5wDhprBKGqibnchF@jzeflK6TUyzoJk7Zv0vlHXYboZLm2q5WVZDkWPubmPBctNOpAWx/3QYs@FhKnLLOVZWJzv8uaMy9OgaJlfPLeSpairVG8auFyWHMsxgyk@35A7dlzX/jw1BUwSN7y6oGcKdJHoTTV2TXwJtz@Q2eCCj0MSnd6qYQXWe4RaIeAH1d2bKn1@cuaNalPA6cchTg0tWleNrDx1bH3Y6eok1Tl109eB4l5MHJ1hq0TtmwZp6PCEIpbE4qx2um7HtHX2mhRyN8Uri9qSth3OeuIsKZsbnc1kJ67wjtEUymp1QT0YmEOTWm8Qr/UunuoQvlYGmrh4r/KemKYhTfZMY1WAkQXN2sHnwmTsnOwSuA4oNgEuMEMFwcYljKHramQ91D3LfbDz6O35WfUwwP5Q75v3Iu1gbkgAV8gwxWlmXD44UCF3sCkZEC0EGwqWzrE59aP30ogPpwZU1Hi4stEZOCz4Bq1s1aLH612YM3AHzsAcsJXGsW0VlQIhBRRwSD1Of4CLnEajhcXP83iwXduexwOyGMZwXLe3NI093ASJe3eWxmc7q8PXa4ep9IA1PjSsJNOBOQY@7ruBOzIFalsV1MYhDfZcxXOiOdqfd6zkRo0WUBG9f174r9Wt@robjEb01R7ZY58@aFSB7lF9nTzRY4sq6PI31@uLL91hRwwdxXDFBZ3GXd6mO1ZgDHCTMKNIs@92jIH1ukyHBxNI0eAGs76R7oaYsYhwF51BoQf0elMR6aU273@Ir/1VlR6Ok7DOIDbc0L8vG4ui23CFkX5s@GzcD02kgkOfc62Lbdat0O3OlRdjK5gBnVuFEw9ksoF2NKzKe7h4YKUkQlfDz9hhuKhgJZVS4RUFVcGUQUBQViW7uC5rrolpGnss5Q2Gaxz3Iva8EpPhghQ6xGXNDT6C@wLpLKykWSpZO4Nx37/O29iYcxekFXys1sjpgtS5cVfoFnQnfK3CoGpLuFMN3m0QP8bmjRMD@RtnBmg4xRZ014JXG15QK@OVw0O2NfLZkwg9dVWwcIENqJlXZ7UYbqbL9cSwYrpmj43jo@l1Mhno1yC89qE/Fwyc6MVhYOTTrNNmPMlx@8CvBZvMAkdhV@lKSxfALK/@uHsT3n9k9nVcDfvACnDd4BKqoO1j2cKZ18L@0lj3rS@NoWSriA0337M5M29@2STalsB7qPct4/5CRcSZDBEcLjpkrwXyR6frdXE6sHxccBMbbhhzQZJjRIxU1wYReknIq4PP8bkDswbE9rItDb1sgNgdTXHLz5SabhobtgI6gBi@V2lRq5Y33ZiJ0/FwNPbD1/I80CU98wOsQ8bO/FMLgAsvgGuSgW4Hywdh50YTQZAK@7uZcXmSFfKBZbt98kFJJiB3BcRCOXcJ4dyBnvcJrhfxnCWUSNN@w7k71PkFJrf5L6BuTVyZ7ljBzQMYQYBrR6I3FoZ1Cu4pyAMP8Cluf14IwtFyjDyY6@TifaSv6aKBwg7dsWeYaIwPh5iXyEPo5m609NXC7fR4uMXpvGZjuDY0IzDYS5uG4TrjQPDGzo3cv3Aj96/gAUFz1U1SX9p7@DQ9X@t0gfDrBMnoCKmZaeXs9hVishyQpVbzy8XQkdh/lx1tc0DXqb4mzg6ev2NQtnzXXaaCPJlCR7GMmY@Hd00D57Jem8Yj96HruNC7jIDxDQ9MthF7YZXB8ogY7QFuNQY8dF@bzCEFu6JTYdKDPjI7UI/2zPQmfQsDfFcP9BVdCx32oipZbHotTVh2x/Q@pONZc@ZVWuNihu6bE6oGrCYM1taEwDCY9IpDTQttYWFywR@5rsOelHvK8FIe3swlgLXTx5vP3oq42ntB9V6qSi0W9fEJW7pgdtlJAavK6pkd12bPGxbEOBabqNY9y/SlB7jxnLoVckQAacq/kVcUb@QVMy0GJNMT3aczx8u1ghlIZfI51qUMdM9wcdImNNywZGRut/hr2HG8gJzNZncA8RPgTLoxDs92fF227GFnSB8rFYC52jwwIZkurlQ7nDqBPrlemWzwJdxfPrfMKN6VHbElbNQFknoC2kV6uQJ3BXvWiD4o5105g0tXigiOZRovdRxocileZsOrC/5QNukRNa4Ybp1rLnQgVNLpNuOlLWZx3RQIIrYpBAMP1HApuGmENjrjYsmQ/nho4rzn4kTCSpHT9Qe0sO7yKd6YiXqmEB63BjwjPnqNyXXCzkqJEcHD//GddyToVNuFXHTuA7Co108qQ@bHnhO@3oTSnrh@0LMmjyHfuLh8FdvAYuUhCrxYC0DTxqpCQO05Y5sNCPTnFv0Mu1SNEujhuYJgU7YcmILpnAj0FK7J9RK5bN@QtIOHqgZmVwg3oeNgufAg2kIUBwvfS@b05nkgrihUJIbYSSEXrjFchtzTiAOA/OQGwsinb2nkP9l/8PhIHPnK0n5oZ4CL7q/JZQu72tWSPDdK9KHuzU3NsbVQXcsPpDuHirD7YF/EACvwzUbvBXjh5NLCa@VQZHSQpqSv1F7Q1wyWC3z3jx4@yMx23JHU7sBzh2Z63nv38DCLGxjeOVzqPR/7HrSOnjtZGX1/T1HSS8g33Ja5iksuSWkVpCMTtEggxvvsUIzXClGGOzK7R9OR@S50ksip/TdMvrCykI/0E6uPrZCUVyKKNlRSFgu59Ny6X1CSTS9@r6rPY2uE3NKgL4m9Vq6QQAlBkzxtuZRw0@T0VWmFyOHk@OeLpMjXqXX@KFdJ9/@pGVMUZRWeD/Ue1CvJr6ysxQDLpjht9@QNZkPNUBkRYichAKoSrNcuVi4KQ2DdEj5wxDx0BGNn5cqMmwDEzoWlDf7UdKa6I6C0FLqM3FjK@MCcm6uJF4uc4DnPS6et4vXWJGVQY4TmI2/Oa3f3zn7kccDcQ9vbj56SJ7oPGs8SiOYcxJlk8aGA4zV4fNeqgYv9rgecmvUT/dFyuq@QQ93rus50MtdUcBYXuzp6YmUcB200kGlbE2sZ7zbY@MyT5StBojTYCnl3uiDnzZ@IEUa4/MqvK4os0/NO8K3IzHqFgEkKTfoUD8ua9zraj0nfwH5ZBIf0Uq3qgTnBFQNslHKZcrqUfxdu4O3F9Gp2eZNf6Qa/3A3pXfNDR9xModwAMH@DH8mLsfcD1z4duOKu7pk3oOOmrJdvyHp5jt@ERzDT2avQvFpoxZXg4WspvR2ZgZcbDdyOlVsQkRd3Tq4cbg90j64/6Lvh4nlmX57U6ThqyA/1l@Z8Ez6e8QFzMMYl40sm0jogiJlO32InrpE7brBHbTdoC/HG0OVzzdbo7nh0hZXg4fRXuNN7oJS5pz65g1t9ZvLhEuUS1xYtd18lTJF4hAkPF7x/tBMl@vhQUudSnOXi/ScLzrgZLnh8OOfmmZPJKm1LmKxSXpb6zFJ9dJRbSHaz/uzkNfsqoGcDVhe/V3a5jO@8c3i9daKmMAiGduTzju6YEZyuG9DdUfE43GQ0Gxx9b0AJIOJjSxZ0QS9iWQDDl9ptPK2k3V5FJUfm@3RgGfpKEpgTFOuZgB8eCmROcoMg/F4HjbKyAbjHMdc@HA0sZxJahjN3XOtGUh/6UYl3yKHtnpJI4ZlrPmGPBVH0E9O5eVOTUNZu7pC1@V53AU/s1P/wtQpFd1b03ndMz1sW5sCQ7kWWd9X0khDvHEYBlvnu2i4Oknat8XCZN42aySzz8hYa9tVI1jIPPLT@eOB6zjLPqGIqlTvmStBrN/gNp6CtLfPo9HrLnPd8d5nzw7EdWCikRZ6P3DG0nois9rxIeqtv1ptNsSLOrHgGrz/w0vMuwCmG7tgH8c6y01eDCh9awYLjFXxTNzwE2HREx70K9x2XfNGa5XO@EC9XYumdezOfxXHiMc4U0t1xM@OqnVKjqfZa8n1p9allOeE51vCK7@x8pX3PdZgtPT/vE52utATafd220qsnQtXXzIQim2P@5ERb1sqA4d@bx@i700ksOT@x6V7d0LarQgH6hpEOvxHh09WXijY3KMCWjKxY9jZj2V/aG@rG/JDjwiEL0bSRP2Pic5qFd/jozs7Re08ehPYv6sNOlEJ0Lrp6l63aitdoXBlGoSfHS4f4FPyBDn0XHUERcNv0lRm093YePInY8QBEckAlHu42N9AU812S6nq@PizHEuTDaJ/SXWh7aJ5xovtT0xXGcaFYf7dMzV@5e@Dq4VA3h5470ulabTwyg8Ox10uv3MiqLld2Dh@sYqvvRMU8fPvhO1@6N9vm9MgaEllU4X@lZYiKKF91Uq87adedcted8tedCqJ8ReZbIQ2KpZs2L2ti@Tps5Vre1esZVa9nVL2eUTXO6JyTfN1pSYpLsKXIS9yuhVPmskFXpsYbx9kGdJA25o/497PhUVPswAa2Td4Xo@8wpFIOMPn04uew5vf840HYqXU8CHad7u@HsOfnZC3cUw8efLRLPzxFAM@LtJyxiccAsA/iBLV1SKZWU/JlsoXfmqoQRaZp4gf6yuxYviixBlk/C3fIVyrKBVmrEb7Ck/CMgviUbXZSNADGM26hUEQ4Vsh6AD7r0f56Qj99Qs4JHb8VDDxKFGyiNH/SSDU8gQDytH72ZP/J3uHRztHTw4bcughPKIhK4TiQWnQOyi2ty0PhQ7yB3szOjacnY9iQHP3eBY77@lG5CH7qabFotYWizQrFb2Gc9TPHkSR6SIMkXED@BJ6lRn1RcAUnBjsqMa2g8HyOCjsvgR77AHXEQPM0Tai0CpGXJTzSfR@KFfpf/Voa9cWv7VXwe3uYcHjUN8jJfdfthin6Jnn9FaV4b2f/wdODPRJlcEY1p1Y3GNTKeXYSfHgIHI9HNtj0NJNkGCUJdVWrJe8lATFJMUkq9FgNego7HhiXjOkBD@QIY2@Q1DqFDxhMxpUi/bePpIukiJs90hA2GWUqCckCzVNCwSPzjoBIyN2D/Xf3Dgjmf@8udUYUIQhyhDv///IHXfYdk@ikrehLg94w1AuhtnzX6lbwoA3DJImcooan9XQJnjLHzqIg5oR@E4RSHh2Umvv2YJqefsTNnw4SHZkxO9UDa45ygPmY7Hsj9LSM@EMn8feaOI6e5gf0fkoPo7xyTmOanoXGvqvITlCNQVPSi76ZgJO2oMdSWcbyLTyrA@uh5469K40Et9HTY0lFsoMfYcRPPer0kzyQ2bETsGPdwqOeEkChYsyrsmSdZpZ9wIefC5jcXING0jH7lkN8xwLRNaiQD4GCccK0ws5yEYR68lqUCHSFmgRUVucCMsV6iAfjE2G0h@fzNT3p8td@RepXCZgDMH8SmifyHbB9LbT1wPx1Zn4mIYFKyWvfbYnzMp8hPLc1LAHLCNezfvYz/C4rn1pXlOO2d5JJ5uUqPJRqnuTJrfWmIKw35Nr2ug6IDF5MmtCcpY3ciXl30Ovu96Umz4N8m5OkjbOzs@S9jSfWszwpCF1LLbyYTC@0gvZicqEppRfHI6XQEF9MWnyplj1uNRst8uTJ@6/ar9L85IQOa6aAwHYf80qOT1TK5GyroCWOy/jNNijhMXkJ13GP4J@aX3bnzDqaOz2g2yRPEs0mfkSVL/LA9pIt@FNO8RwuxjMadbEubrVevUo3dD2YTIllWSO/24XbHZCUqqYPCTS129CIWASJNOmbIhGu/HDSI5Mds98f7@lTa3wv2BaLYklU5xjT5sMP3guv6ntPnxLylDx9@vJgBRtrZTIpQWhQ8yRyfAAiZ3ZCKm09n8Cvrv3lZ2sX2bMn7c2//HgomWv4eoyvTy4eovlQyd9aW7t1504ul1VVlZmffPDkF3d2dnJ3s/knjfxWTpDXNv/iz9fWVHVTldZavq@0ko3j4/d5Vc7x4l9@P9l@8uRLvl/X/utHr@oKPorwOCFFUsZLIwoY8VmCWyH5PHnTK/EyocCVmNJfOxG5n60Rpb5V/O/ffPwiESTqqvSeB@8g8SJRKCWYEQxg0yLbSaKe2MRghYvEVKrVamAs/vd/D/Hr7wAc9JluwqOej2AVpom6UKNRzhP1AhgUVYV0/@@PPprLIfAzYCU1aJFCKXLbBobYaPC5ospvteDaoNcmh0ccCbIkReGcYBCYLlFKt5XbaLHAAi8HXjgu1UzgdycfbxPx2UEG@oSM@G59Tbq7KcAljiRFUZuKchvYr3Bro1YToF@hzVbT8rfx@Mk07Q37buAS8/Z7C1fivf8h11Iw1ff@ea4DsmsZpudmuURhbfv53XodSq7VtY16hl5hc6Mtr1jiXXcbuM7RYOxZLn7KsvoAP8pS5@WSymez2e2DNkQhkwkiU5hMxDaCIOxD2Ql2iW3CXLBhh46MKuGqI09okdidxYqss3DkebIBraX1fHW4xB5ef/Uf/@rbf/VN@vs2vf8znhTldK2etAGBTqDh1OHarlSMep2ve/xZE@11oDa5UqqUpPZFM7XRqLcOQMB9@zyZ15Lk0J5m2ypezXSzQePXabL1MHm01xMz5zpzqc@7hR4sMHWAd4gpkojKOVeuGGuEXAnHJaJFTkLjpN4ScJy0JjSUQr4lsFiNbagcXi2W@XYrIaxPMe@tuppXH5PtOrvIYN0nLuZGUwtRQcL81mdlm/nMbPV5p0Q9ilafhfm84cI8laFkvhTKnvUoo9trlbVSpVBRpXZ99VWdxcCLBjVN84mfOEnEV5WEdBjhMxFT5pzbs/maiKuFRARMFuK@JhyXaNQaLbMFbWT2v3bR6tIKCl8NTWqbJ1WgD1UT1H6blxVobdvtiJ1vwbUGP/qHK7bic426hM40yPVrjVSUDVWT8rcKeyr2wVcv4gmNeobySKFVz4jIKwXxSiAOehVidDqdl0YHZBRd7@iGrgT6WJ/oUz3ojDuTTmCMDfxCMXmCgl47RICnuXm35Eb4EIWEllfWE7eRwjW1jB/7BS2lVNLKqlZUtGJBK8pqKa@VyloxpxWLAFArqlq5nFNVrVDUCiWtUNAKZfygMoQpQBgNIRTzWlnjEq8aa@SA8bcJyURXM/Pa66lIORpe1ODiLQjuJAEi1Ng4znKJf4arrqgK2YBuUoYHyIbUSFT6gxLu6tbYz3IkAWLfWevVRuPVBpmvLSHMM7zE9nYrI1xcNMBcrYb/zXpsrNKLmaCorYtMZvNZHaShZ/VGBkA@C0GKAqFAxXadtDapV5xamFzov9lq9cE3M/L7SDICzcQLyERms7FZc3fpLdLWKbQglc2FnG9vU1Lbhlj1degW0pnMuiCsNQB0I@ygIDASZFhEgATBUiDKnJ39nDfZ3AQmc7F5Ub9obF5cbG7Cf5M@L8I3uIL3RTLnJgvu9ia1xH/6ml0Xi75RmJl/C/lUsyHVm1Iz5FUtsItSHV1EqQmGOrwhXENTSy3sHVEOElv/Mv9idvaMXTDLLRFyzSU2yEYCz1jSEhtc4vnlp/8r3s3LT3@IMi2Bn1nhEmeEcAlpo0yoG32VQbB76JCH7HLAjHdkRRd0qD9ER4c9HNSUJem5SCoCVZdTSqmQFrH7b7u9Nm5iFclzCArB9vomNKKI9xJeLRX4dkaZqiSxyReKlN3@wrUrmUz@q@dquZhk2jjuwnzu@/7DuVzO8gmBq6qsCMp5nR2Wy04z/4Vl17/6hVUXlzgvE8RRijC8cAkgo4QkgRbJJeqbQ1wSiF8CEfCTbie194WnO8KuOxzpAVXXcSwPRIXa/l6tXK6jGmWuP6GNZ@PuBjwV@O@tQSFIswdBm72aMQQRvdnT8moTtda3ddDegdEJnRf4e/ASf@TIwN/BC/yRo5f4OwjwRx528Hf0An87HfwdDfF35wX@Hr7E39M@/ppf0DSlyq/rJ91JF/6Tl@uT9TOKq4xSVi7WJzzDWWKr3vwCoNNPVsl28gsNOiqUL7ca6NsCjy8E3rSi18rVUU2tDmtCTs1VX9ZUQa2GH75w/aw/9bO4ktM0sCZMI8WrWyqfrjJK0XLl9BfYOE2lXbPpoAtJ4XdEUq6fzoAhBZ1YOgr@SghBiZYffYMwxTb/VtQ0DpFo5bzrCTqxfHiAQ0YrK66X/Ok3Pv44WaslhSQ9Lz4HbgJ@hBoe4NAoZxU1W8zmskopq2ShHHJWKWYVOVsCvVJSs2o2ny1kh9mXWS2rwL/VaLSfNVSwvYSfCncu@7LVAP6av11stRovW7eUciuTUyEzkKVc@guABiKa7INU1RHgi0vUyLqyrsi2bMhKR@mAwSKyR@SBPFC6ClU2ZZPIU3lK5KGrdMFkwk8GkyX3iNwnsiM7EAx8wRS05QBNPXj14dcDQB78LFwJ1VFkg0BCNiqk9FNQShtjyuS8Td4euH6QHTW5BkkS/rn5/PlzHHcXC1YLvwzQ4J8/b0obLbVcIiK2PbHdeN5Mtvgmj@fGquUc6UzNteZzHiQomWdtFF1IwvcbyVY1ITWbEqtBQD2lrYuLdnvv0d12W8KuvEnMemY7A/3Q9nYN@qXwtZWoV7eaFdrTRb1dQtrcatY1Ac2FDHRaKriR@yaQTlbKfM5rBhje9TWKgNbz0@egsKVOUW07PYHXaWR4rwmPNlPoqLd0@l5zzkoNcGFYSXpvCYQFA@Ta8aaxcAZ/0H//uf7Wv6z/w6cknWq00qmzi80UvdL4S6fPLs4uwmc9nUqFltQm/NAB7Bjl7KKORhroDEyNVLqVvrhgbvBMpTcZwHqapDbrNO4sHHR7iThJmix7pP7HvElcmFR4NZPV5/zmpmecN6uUiebkMknwz0F50mdTI83mRAbm0InOsxYcsq6f03HkdNXAj8WtdxpK6y@@T88s30rTQPlctapsEGZRc2q1motsxVK1Woos66lU@fpVl7eUAqh4uRyw2CpYtiKwMlghboO8ypAaacKzdfs2S6Sknp9HMLVcISPjlFS1GqWUh2RNXzdoOwfN72z/MT3vGxhFPkGQH4SD6imZfi/gRLdTyfV2rTK5fTsVfhN2ayd9@7Zals/PFbmUaZSQA8tZTStmhXK@1ahMROh/B27Xp1MOtwqtJEm7XuoRfr8TgKYEhdxS6xR@GTiwmiuidyMPQBS41awA@k0r3QCuwTobnmedDdLbrRJwbq0MZYoVxSSfrPKJMxCoSkWrR9bW24yL8VX0If9irgQBxgKcZPEiZxcJSmQkl0@ngDOnQQS/SODPQybOeuJ8Pl3NyXLi7IJngZVymYVOk1whVcqUw19tLU3qIF@yHwrJWia3UdzYxtFC358sv5DPV8/MmnJROzMr@CGbi6oRftARt0qbt29rZajvkpwgd8d4YEO2yYWdRA1kDRRV4dHkkskMuXWbw33kXrJS3aZEp5TyJJGsMkchCZ0NKZUziqRu5JUS1hVn9fAABJC3OIWiao2scSp944MrMwSuoWOCS8wPG9z457pwkS7pkD5epI9qPbGITS9iE@ZPn4YRB3LZFfrGVhqXDgRELmZ8sWkNLa@xhpUkD8aGhQOKTx7s7O4dZdVNgSTUezu7WfXw6Z2Egtb8zE69NbQf7O3cffwUIjx5sLdzuPf2/rt7T5@Au09OZ1fcp0U9W9zDzZmW2E/Je9yH3kvdNHVzbJrt0/H49AX50LLaFlS5PYayuX2P@GYbijTSZ8Wrwm1Yvv7hh7o3ohe5/N5XLr/3S5e//43L3//K5e9/@6effvsrcP8A7m@w9zf@uJzH508//fU/vPy93wfH/wz3n8H92U8//e2P2E3tP4L7v8y5/Si858KxmwNYX/vpp9/8/k8//fp34P7d8P7O9fvXPlt@f/vLq2@M980/vDnMN/493H/EYEVhv/F7zA3f18L/Hgv39e9c/uZ/YP@/CH9o/P3L3/wRPkLLr37nL/7L5cf/SVVLf/FvL7/8zcsvf3z55U8uv/yv1cvf/reKPP/4w8tv/8nf/Okf/c2f/hv6/wF9/tGb/C@/86t//b/99f/@138a3p/B/R/A9Nlf/ydoxn//J9/D/zf/5O//7Hv4/1/@4O//5Ft//7X/mRp@hxn@8Xf/mD1//PFXfvzl3/jxx5@ueH7lxuenb@D@6T@Dy5vn803gvEm5Pq/Lpz9Xfv4p2JilAjQAlPvLl7/9VSDe34RO6/IrP8B9G3Cv@P9AVWiYHzDb/wcM6vUyo48MJri/dfmVb5D3EUv/E2AJ/uT996F3ej/s5t9///0Qg5@gH7i/Tx3ZtRiReUa@M59PyCwcVMN3CWk8f97CKeMF0NTy009/4/vUljArdTodiL1@SS1lNkBt2yiX43nCTQz/1RjkF2a/xCKkfElzHKca5uAT5GILiX2C/O/yex9dfv9fX37vdy6/9zXs/4VcObuTFZTXCEEQMP8G4TBg4U3CYUBIvp2h46VCBszmuYQbi7bPCalCObSS1pwFN6Veb6MCPwKPSmXjLCtsNUmBlfiCxsWdSSDbKoJ6K7O1JhFFz2obmg4BpRwLRyrOtpzLFDd0XeLa5xLuYiLnZM4oKSykpIa4ZF64UksKIUuKGnutRwDiYnCJDGY3QyWijUhOy2tkkglLMgmn5tEdAk02qHFC2GzKhHpPuAmdwY/@M@OEIxkqJDEpNDMzUkMYL5r9L8IdFiQPaWVmEzZUeiRMcNtgLnRhA008B5oUnQvNTGp1NOBcA3jdAb2lVstgxBrLFFhZ/uolQvOTydSg8Bibxcm2SwhicodCgZg1iofahEXMILx6hJMMh040N5lS7S4kWJvcRYcMAqdgnz@v1Uu1SR3BvWJIyUwyd2ieEFgtM6m/AnuNwoR4XOLuK8hKqZbJ1EuYIBaS1VG2zWoqTwtHy46z6qwi4I1L27a2CbnFKyWezVitIcJYaHxmZqExIEY5eM4rKv@cz6kyD4GbmY2wbPQfGem9QbG/RtMNk2Rlx5TXKDDSfr7xPAxIQ0JqgiCKIoEbl5FskW2yxTGsZTI0M/DKhEikxEKJI3YgFFNchtY6QxvAB2f6PU@iqrkq6CdVgk6eweHnv@jaJJlbn@C6szMSysxy@E3LC06HMDlZ487O9XBd2rpOLsCpwGEImmZt43NfmFnE2vr6Opeo8xr/mM6/ZySJeMcVuroQ2h7VtCqEL5R5dDbpUkuGxYe4XSHLUXMVi0kuP/p@IicXE9x6kn4/mLCEyK0Mu7e3N8gtQCt9z7lN6CI@IaO5OTfB0LiZyfAqJFp3wbZBUZih0LhnJFHDP7gnKLlBb/xE9yw/y2Up48vCS6wl0Js8fvw4zC91eFbjMtAOVU1BO869jsdjiG52cZ1DNiuKWTGbDd8ifVMHMTSI1Dd8i@uIejKvESrFEn441DEGiBfu1atXQBsc4qKy7wShkdTUXIl6EkoGE1xepw@zHDtWwban0SpeNVfm2FALUQo5QlKUIuBKE1yumgIaT3NszRsjr@hKJdVSKUlDQo2JKQjGwBQU5FRsXTDdQEXyxQUr5GzeimOnbBoBF2DEC3JZ/lKlfDry3H1Mdh8/fLj36GjUqrWgt6FfqjXbI881TN9PoefOo7uMftVyIY2z3Vj6o4qKvJPbq8hIyJn9uwf7hxXCcBZWXoqWpEpXL4SYKStcYjR6bzPh4WSGZ/L4nSaXP8RnZYaMlFrWIGqiziUMExU0oFT8w10lB2YfCfih37/jTkhKzvJ8VimgWp3G5QWQnV90xwTPYWSHPwB/wNWTIpQYc14/E@am89ChTg5UjhkEhRqIVi5FhiIzKMUCBnjMPmGmcfXDvSOAfPSYKKoskgO3Y0Gm6u@TiUgIcIEDd2i6WeGCxkaedGQNXQxh4@RDPxis42dh@abMzyFovSFn8adqGg4g5QpZJV9sra3ZZwLCaVKiOcO1oRdgPRMQJ2/BRbi3OPIWOMElXBDOHZkOCWdG9h9XGfnitmKSgtwfBh6v5IEzpDmcAArhcaP5q4pYh6a2OJXKJdY@@CAg9freo7vC/j0cvZgMSLSyVLC64kCkpNMdeyb17RPStd61cMuD2LX8ka1PoR0DwjbqgJEA57kTFxcXPYC5f4@odZVaWdwuPi8M6tIB88VE5wjw6B6XuB0N2HDF25VK7ZWSK0LeKpVXmqpy4MBtSFzC6q0BudG1QRsS@/FOLafIGSWc5XFImuf5qg@Z0rSStMElFJ6Hl6ZpHG1DhKuYHKFrx17JtZoQsvmcQpeOcXg6vT6pqfEVhp3cmoXVZBYWfcCD9AOPyJFfkfmFtqhngKLgYmr6gdJoDFO@fVvDYSstJ8dlJxQ15ALqdF3LabSS7plOgHRG0LeVyBXDyUkoZyvB2WZAujUwJ5pYcJouW5yOH4n3yRhCFnLAFE8rqkLXiVdyai7BEwyNrFIryVyikQAewDVawAv@X/@1Glxr8i/3D2hpNGrcBHjp/B06Yxj6Di@Oe@g@nv0fPx7OW2/8Dx@7Dx@7Qxf@0Fs@RCZfnf2r1QXrzf@QtyJ7rVYhq4E5AXqDX07Og/Ufv/3RP/zmf/yH3/pExCu0xQ7/@O1vMfff/XV8fuvb//CtX/qHb/0Wdfm1f/jdfxN6/ePv/gG5C0xg@lJH2rz8@seXn/7x5Q8/u/z4u5c//FO0zv8//Xeh18ffmjmCGV2u/L9F/vbX/o@/@@4nf/PZR3/3rc/@7nf@5McffV0tKT/@6Ff@7nc@@5s/@xoB@09@9NUff/S1v/2Vj3/80S9DuPn/T370SeT15dgRzOBy/Q/uAJf7/68bL2TQuNqDLmDYDI/rrNO9CA2lnGvtAY9rkNZmdJJnHUJvsp2KBI9iqfFIgFJgMTe@7pt2T8QV/jV@c1TXZJXfDI8Dr5N3TQf7kDB@vVvrugb9mHe1K1r4UXXck8fi5XJ81XXw0L5aNKMPkkb6rF87pXvtq2atL@LxMJ6j2xC943anoh9MQUg0XNv1aklQeZMgZ79ruTalYjDvdF0HZVinZoKahZMNW5qWq0D5xJE72lLzRYEIDUUGwRNvpZTtQj/obUH/W1Gza@ZWsVjpioZt6t5WvpJHbyNe27GVlyt98f2HD@4HwegAJCbTD7ZyZYiAR6zhYUhbpUo@DyyF5zMNmmILv1LMBAxhbQ36Y1PvCvDGpR@@oJZaFZp@rZZMbmmKKigVTS5xYWFnCHOqjpBTCltyJZhHI9mzLcf1sjyHH1ONawErcKDUc3JuU4I3gbrHdSggTtXJjtk3sT@iNadsSiOkCTBCUB2MHTDmN6UOGC0wljclC4zjuqbIm9IYjEY9p4CrwagEa4NY3RqkiSXLYLazSC7ZgXIWyhcVx3XMC66S1bPWGa25Sq/Xu9g4y8wsJLFN156rV9aen4HediawcFDbF4Ke7ZzF1qowg8BVyDgrWDNPcNF7QDxn4YKcCq/mS3y1UZ3ZiwW@2rrgtodm19LxE9lN@ex6rAKIhAxqAhJqEu6i4rluUOmYPdczZwE1pRAFZBm6HiDHX8TJNWVM8ex6coW5QJOzGV5jfHZs1zgOU6JfjlyWVi7PX3BGiA7P7F6whLKVbOTIolKywWrECk08e8YlNg7e1ep1oNuzXFHN5XN5VSsU8kUVxN9yrpAvAdnIBTmvqsA8cuVSuXgBrVaSXiXop@fI7lnUmiv04wMpvcKO5Gy0SPrVI8s@K2kCYz@pdBXEpcQrLnHr4F21Xl89DpcCVeJdVajXtHwZTBqaVI0KVaoqqJqgKYKi4f81BhX/bx5ehb@KT4ilqdwRHlj0CKR4UGAc8gDPXAlccuS6dJfZHdNYEWJ3oNPDkXY91/f/CWHu6M4x87prsdNxY6/7On6izR9awWBFiKejoeX4uFXtnwvC3rADGURuzwLcgYdnu@6yAEXy9Ak8Dvbfvn8Uv5eX@mF83jwghx04DzGO9nZ273MFcufxo7tXXvkQXJ482Lt3FFuLzDeKmo9B/OLegwdXreEr9/jpQW/senhz9x4/zc0esRNuzuNycC0Gip0pkPCBVhTxUFUhayRfjAwKh/sCb@fK5HZozBdmRhmN77Gdh5Yfbx1km1cr3FG0HVEn2AV0TIKftDK7dIiWHr8YjmwoxTLHjYjjnpKiTLqubev4zfjeGjgOdJ90TBPVdNtGSsSkT13P7p5aXXMNRGNIo6zg97kxE9x9ADIcGwNMALQkPLS3i19zx6UYHXtskvGIrHSEFzqh0bP6A5A0Tt0oANfRdQL3570gvjl/BTc7BCwN6nbNx74enEtwO49xACZR4vldnr@vB7pUfEZQfhpU@CDP93GG2/aDbkOtgnq3tpUrAZvflXHc3SLqVJcUqQpIVArndXdb2Wib/Vq@oGxhX1yTM9uJ@2apVL0HF8/7upMFJpmt4EDKrldzrGfEqDpqBdT74gYhTfPczuRqikwqFTaauav7bkAapNSiFFb52@/@4Cd//q3Lr352@cPfQiGQ3HU9Q8eF7KiNE6pbh0q5SAeD1HIpXyprailbKpdyeaWQz@PqSKVYKpblrCIrJaVQypeVbClXBukth2sn8@ViqNJL0gbZsXEUL8vUdmmjAuAdAz9bvUnHlcRBnUuwhT7kZUpPk4Qe28eENyEOT3acvmkDDBwQDOh@2A2rBn03gaJqRQKQdWKQxL17uzLi6Q5acFnjrszzXbTkS7JcvMPzJvXZLaGAyrssTgnPYuQDZpHlO1CNYwYAPz/A8wO07BVwlobnLbTs7rD66KFFxfgQ7Jj5MIsdWYoQzEGLpjEAL2JoEGyHpZOjGd1DCyaJPveYzy748fzbUXbQ54AFYwDuRyXd2eH5fWbZ2UGfXVrsPMvoF9GyQy@e98ACbYzn@2Doe9C6eb4DRmxpPG@AyZjq4IafCseT651A5/kpQw8iiOcnNLRuHPN8O3LHZN4Nc5NH7FaoRWGl3qaWMv54Xo0yjcG02KLxfC625KBs9@@/qw@Crtln19RjbwNKev@@pluT8d69zttvd/r9jjfd2Xv7AL12d@@DVDMde51@J4zYacPlQqzd@6p@PJxevaDU@@12RbeXen2x3c7pzhWv9rRtYg4h1gvIWXj1MaFhexe8du@3t/VlK58owDYymSG8O3jdGcL7jt5hXtFFveh70unwVWgGoMs0UxyqX7h4CZvnMTBtJzvUDc@ton1SIzJdTz9tFORWlXqQIehPcvUC/XspfOo46J4@mzYmNblVm9SKKhtq66X45kTNW3x2bbillPOVNX1LUXOZSQXX1bm9JEkKyhZJKbc3XpLUo/SWClrUGt/c2hL4htLaKhSfbYyh4vGxpSqlSk5WSZpZtWIF4shJmRB8pBvF1lYxX5lFLhYzuqRWikWQ/wA/AUgRHRzlbpNU6tTUj9NpzDodJYXy0IKTKS20Ve2lJtlJjWWSTNPVSU2psuOeiXwFWirVxW8IjA08a4YwoH0AOAE1CtclpnilXOIhD5KEizdx7I4h5ywnly7Ozvyzs@ZFzColMM3Gqd/70tHx0dH7wK1ALJmy4b16OML7xDOR50VL4d@@vyvuP45s@HkA8R5KyK4n7iKPW/BhonLkdASalHgf@nbQoiM3iBN4ri3u0bXzIGZHHtEZPWJ4hK94dH8BzuHAPWUpQyS/ipKcjoco4NcTrC7Ra3Uw6V2SorkievqUShXter3Wrg3N4SiYQhGjWF8k9NMCMzD7Pss7/ZoLfuueRj/ree4w9GjX5ItqpzZJTASB7ICQN/ayALFdI4LyfOh2n6sZo9rFzyfcqd1BMNU2vDtVs2Z6nuvxoMby1d6WUxs7vt4zn5gengyx/3gdpB08WCXVI2Z6nTT3MPQuKlcXQt0jziyPj8bDlC7UO@lFJ5wViR0QTakvRcU/w1kByDnPX1R7NZJ6BkFfgN1bJ6mueCe9lasCxu6Qdhqc5Oe95z2ikkKuSnWhFMKCJkgxhRjQ07X6F0FIY6CPoeuG3IRVfgxQMTEADLVBffT0yLqoGjWbpAQySVMc5ar9WgOjn@NjUwA5QxAa5y2c1HgPFYQXY@g869Dcq9OEXvPHHfpBHSJ3FFUuVCfgphRz1QHUt/5sUvVqo7FnVm2whtMghJZYrwJuAYUA5uV56vKrH6U3hXyNuVUpqHMcu26L7dqk6uBRqEApNa0GHplGTs7mS1l4FLMgQqiFrFLIatlcViiW6DrcEt1UgbpYa20tZad4QvisPJFFJauYSjYlP7e6z9PZ4xQKNxR56Wzg7jnjIUEXqDKkVmqHt57OqBuAoq5L9E2BEi8wmSqWC3A/ICMrO6CQDkzdZhHSAtE2UvZ6CgOtH41He41WpbI3GX0JvFLCi61CpihnXqbT1dRauuabL@iU0R0LCEQH5CJnosUfrQFNh1NFxB8PG1DrYFKKaqXR6GBZi3JWkzUoptU@72/ydb6VldcKCtTZBZ0RUAjjLPOTIyA5cTO3URuVBduEOlTKapWje0kS5I43prM1WkkVylJ@Iy@zGRIGghuFLBJxS1LNaNtNMpVMFtVkcqZZp5NVnI1e42eTg1TfPqMcMgksmyRvq/nCFg8CIF/hyyoPwWYcF3NJ5CjnG2RXN33dw1kkDscrSA709TPu4uxis85NRG5vaNmWniWOZeCX6SzjWOTuuV43SzpWn/T0ANuyyO1AafcrIncIyp5JTY09/DoBYfHpmSgYrRUCrNAptmAwHZigEYnclM44BuJ1V6glgu8oqcUQ5AvcIR6psak@w1/x2cOdx/i7t53ALSpk@wvgVwb30rOHTx8/fXyPHpsw2838ea5tjkh0H8pEbFcTVTrwj8szIBksWuVzrP7exkl4Iq3heQAkIwpinZ45sc1SaYanH0lrhHzejTKZzfoz9m7iflAAzdGj0RukRZeKmxbq6uRdHQTKLZKEKte9YUNVtVZDLYJYAl1XQ2ZBVVWpQi7aCbq5uQ70PTmDTG9m6niyxBfJdKpnhKjot0m9n1mX1WnipM0Xyho9/KBdV@Rjspa8vYHf/BZI4uR4ra5uZJJPKlomeTep5RInqeZ6PaNMkxLZyKjTHi5UwyVRUhLCqebGLW0j@TRTKfWzFSWDTxWelSQR1hLb7ex2uuxzlJJJYgHBa@Wd2k7/YCda8b@zWy@p0/BEjMSzNl8qhllsrgPK1Myz7YX4dZCFnuH07ZV6@3mW@m/jSvhkNZk4S5JE8iJ50Ui2AHSjER@wUmvNso/r@sLFD1quQNIJkg5txXLCT8UrD76Q3E4kcXqf@P4rIGhaD7RZR2cffPG5Ckwm4biRgzsOcKgXxKh8HievE9Lzkf@BWtIe7j927nr3TC7RXDtfc3FhAqnyDCRPXjnvfAmUWKitJGnWEpNaLpz9Vep1QdlU8byzIqmAANBTCoJ8XmecrE49Cir4XH71O7nJZgnsqqyAXVXzGbVeVzZABE2MLj/9YeBNydneuzsPSBLnkn/y599Xiz/58z@g6@eTF3R@WdWKCQiJRqVQTJydjc7OQAC8YH75RCtxbS1gC9AkKXq5uCFWK0QqlcobYltKMHSCqFxU0glfSIS7Kgp5IZVSJDW9oZXkNPich2dKpVS5BNZonQd14gt5Pp3YO7DyqrK9uQUl29JyanWt0eCVeEicxL9N0y8nuETp4fNzQsBi1Lv9vqVSkySFbeiVQDZfCZvwhhp@JayR57U6LmhU8CSXaMnABp4CgWt4kvWMtJEkoGeTeuOietHK0HUHdOjj2YbTvIKM5hpuG1502nDgZ2749Gea1EodfLBGNnPjQ59PbaQlqdulfQ6u@RCEeoKRbNsk@TrQy4YEudyIlgmwnyA005df/W1VLfzkz3/tvH3efl9V1XK5XFDUxM9@tjl2xr7Zrf8MIj6JTu8DIjKsLhLrkXtsOr4YjzfQjs5y8MtklhOPUxB2OKQVxooNosFzibGDuhgLH41a4PgEAXnU6jtml45WcCcoTdNqbbPz8ropGmyDgDKSpbocPaArXeW4SM9huprXN7IUBtnAg6QbrTR3xr2FXrg/FvS9KvfWDBQ4DEEac422b4@9Ed1unaLxlFaW3IYokMJbeBbhGoROk7DPFoALQz99LSrLsk@xRuVtgmee48mGIIpwb0GU8OB7e0pGuuebNKTlgJwgYhCaT@rRxd1VLUjbZhHa1DVFS88CZAnLHYvkgArHvQWyJcWCBSInsTYhQBV4yluAAChDKgRstcgm0dLkzMpkqrNjEy/wkBzHBRRG5/pxGA2hdQFNceQqhgMnUB3x675IF2ENA9@bc4yAMBhsEV8NlE@MTm0ozFtADpM3BgWwTgdYQ7Ro5PbtWa5qNaubJrRECP/YGuGALa0HZ3leAVikxd8ClgriVCaDlf3WItkBxjM0u0B1AjuJsjoXlfBoveA4@L8x0SJFXqkq6lHFAoT1xVqFASiDyIh2VocG2awRRS2mSZx5A/Ju0EzRU5/ioYnm5Jaovh95XkAOf5aIPtQFzOpofhA8pNu7pn0@PI8R7hNQwMb08NpgoDNm0DVta4irA3HIGpnefhDFjmNBUSybhu5ZHqjBdK1gdBxiSlPSGG12fCTNB93TqOYIbjjMp/FFY2FoAm8dj@cL01mjoqvhQoX6I9eh5/kFyJpwaydQBPAoSOCRG5gs22PnFL@eF9YNjTyfIyglaDlI@Zhjej6h65g@i4tL7jqeqR9HuMkSsy8SY9glapmkKKE5uLbEicGlaSSa4Q5oT4jjjm0OIUuHpklPPfArktQHoW/cwYlx6aEFdDW4Z0H34/jSXYZg6dQ6tqQjPCldcHt4OAIFDlBATsTmxxbtgaI5trvEdt1jYlvHJpvbSM2fjYgfJClkQfHJAmZnNyC2giKvqmVxEEzJslBwF@FVZMZSdi7uWmqavv7WlLVUG2v0nPZgFtSKbZ7ozhx@6XXOhQMp/tTn6FGQNYKKQwrsYsxyoWWyU9WSeNBhMi0C7rsgYdH69SEKxhRxzmyU4hN8WvRHthVQIzfyzBOCAyEc9jHANI12mAVsxVDat2gHQNsetCw8njHwKlBzGciJ100Z0PRCBu@QW0RTOQwIKWNQlgGAgVVfW4QOfhAVy@EHXagYkU4UIV@B1jnsgh8e/xaSH8aPqBvN9LDMGXmTtRAcdjo0rRphzSKy5Ocs2DqQnmnR18CzADlckpO1FJ8BsBk@zTPQcfyr0Rm1c5SXVMh1SFmCEEJUAxQqKujIcvD86LnP3@FKkjs6cGf8wgFSPRD96empSE8iHXuWaPr4STjfdXRbGvUtEIddKTCHo/Cj2ZYhjSK4M5PAvvgojgajrQkKtbXy7Sl7c1zPr4VrcFPJnp/EzvEEv3jWH56gbgUZ7vmUoO5Z9KuIRipcE8zoT21lzyL6qyTpsX7JCwRCCIKZZKdZIwvAsh3jONs77VZDjxPaIAE41KIZOeL5wF5kGfqRyRr14hBugHw09urYx3RRAUDi2WzBLGlWwijkNLKG9pGFi/cd85TseJ4@TVH/NIZGAk5NqdhD/p/2vn4/bSRZ9O/oKTo4GZAtvhzbyWDjWWxwwq5jcgAnk4sZVgaBmQHEIGzDZHx@5yHue9xXOa9xn@Le@uiWWkLYTjIfZ/c3e87EQuqurq6u7q6qrqpewrZPX@ARthnxiZPVDhetZTtUfeFXh03NdyuChTyFO9e9QDlzMX5f8PcFfF/w90XQqGq2tWizSIav7rA7yPUYhaBKIpilKnPHWX6DLwQZ5HCRZxBYchl6h77K3SLVVvTmXzCORcUYwBNTILiTyrZ@uGhdtCeec7vZ3soOgNkTRAgYcQDdahNNb3v@M1J/dDOaul7oFWwfJN5IvPFV90pyA/MK9tEfIGIMptcQM7MOxtLdiQUC2WGAgHIYfETRoDRPDc19P1U2fQTGaSUCGjNiLYlMm6Qv@Um@A3GJSc@E1QG1NUD43u8SoAlfhJo5fAGoWh0@zFwoo8qm6c5CWCKXItlOAiUjU4XXmn0aJA2rdFqhCWRHcbUY7Yr6DkPRinzSunknx19H/@lno9@HeRGPPTEsbxj7hj5VMOIARAg5XYiq4rCojStgkN20R84Mdq4Ky6dyt4ZmNrNKzeB2sAve7XDevUppg981eXwotUVikij4rLAsFqGLyyJPS54XiqRMcL@aJ6stFSPI@ryAAIxcbDVHVlvo1RbFIi8cYrGm2q2G5IKQXHAVLr1Yg2RbVgPtqaq2FxyeNkinGAqRAHh53kZBDJomhGffOOjG8eP1eIpalWozWHOICyQPoYiNfNZtx7be0pDWFq0IAGTEFQA9vhu8YEQXvHza/@WvUUxKtUbxL8kGvFYAg9ESvG@wDuQzGenAIPAntmgfgLmb2GoZiTwdE@StvEzbkU9Y6qX6L7/6MhcumQ@/zFmR//tdXraRstoE1aSPfG4HF2QjsFToJou3LmiDgR1Cc5jQXuFBUfgdLAATKsYa3BihpEhxu9e8QPYFnuLMHviRpKhg5YQlSupjvNBYiXOPMnxTI4Kyu92CnnExSZj72iUDysoQbIxCnFRPK2KTol76JDgroTkxS7CUwmg8HU7uQ4BO9kjyxklEVovnXgH@AxwsBRLIRPaLFNHGfBA3osjldb9F6bHkRCA@Fam8jg0i2AfleIJH61biuScS1jdQ0UTGrdROTCOcrV8ekYTqA3LedJKCWlYinUlQVXiH6WgQUhgEjya@VwgDyiibKkUMFQq89i5D1/04C@jKZOCQYmZn869ye98a1LuJNbfGrW/b1ma3mBCwBNmTsXc9u@39NHCvbvpiJKY/Xi66y19@FmJ3R2Aqz@1vOBozv1fMUuwYRemKb3N0z4JE8DuKN8U86Rllzk4KumGBwxeeCrrtQZCfQgFlwgiXis2x4kI0KsyL49ZeuziBRXjcmrT30awx3yrOt/JbKXzxTd7ENEpYM9VtzdtAlzttFm0ar23QavAmTlG69OjgE/Y0I2QumMMO6eEJLB1c4PVMoyEI@sRMt6SQylBBUFaAYQOI@vXYRrWPmj2Vt/BJqvdQKSNqCPl2iEKJ/8HDy/w82mHxeHWO1wYASDzqAgmDsvbDLvtim5V2R2CPsBTs2gMdCRxxNMfg9PfvAsgY8l4Eg7tKfUHjGN6kLFBxxRN/2KkLhvEf18PuT8evxXYu9zKfe5HXSIbX5yKCucyLnWC7AiKpD9vo4rOb3zGMY3e6ZL892MwR1k4aAVriFJXj96CXOTfOZOIYpdGIHfw8vL7Cmd04vYxh1J0e@Y5eXhNFUI27RnKBVutez7p858HlcGLPlsgXeCEL3ZIAkx//omPiGFSdvrwv0DLQCgIK2Xg4Z1uJezPEu0V8y0/fHY3cWyRYF40uTA@sNHZgjzM2TRFGCYmlcCF9f3ztzXFKo9UYAdqXeLtt1yfDBDa/LowMmTCMEYAiw53W2KQXwQTa645sVLUycQhAQxoFFALQtd5117kXB4OQ@EwchOyYitew1chk3Znh0lwZ26jaglwXEJhGhappuMMAN99UG6JRO2l@KNUrAp7f1Wvvq@VKWRx9FM03FXFce/eRvHLFm9ppuVJvCAxrPa6dNevVo/NmDV4kSg2omaAPRunso6h8/65eaTRErS6qb9@dVgEagK@XzprVSsMS1bPj0/Ny9ey1JQCCOKs1xWn1bbUJxZo1i1pV1YygnqidiLeV@vEb@Fk6qp5Wmx@pxZNq8wwbO4HWSuJdqd6sHp@fluri3Xn9Xa1REdgxo1xtHJ@Wqm8r5Qy0D22KyvvKWVM03pROTyMdrX04q9QR@VAvjyqAZekItkdsifpZrtYrx03sUPB0DMQDBE8t0XhXOa7iQ@X7CnSnVP9oSaCNyn@cQyH4KMqlt6XX0Dkj9QBVYFyOz@sVPIlCSjTOjxrNavO8WRGva7Uy0bpRqb@vHlca@8I4rTWIYOeNigVtNEvUNMAAasF3eD46b1SJbtWzZqVeP3/XrNbOTBjkDxW8@uW4BFXLRODaGfcWiFSrf0SoSAcaAEt8eFOB93WkKVGrhFRoANWOm3oxaBCI2NS7Kc4qr0@rrytnxxX8XEMwH6qNigkDVm1gAYCJ7X4oQaPn1GscJ8CLH4FZDcW5Fg2nqJ6IUvl9FTGXpYEDGlXJLUS24zeS5hl0rtUEtCHe0OjYY11o66@@unHQIWxV2ouX//zzp@NauSIS6twwEXw4h13nVeRgSv8GO43/EX6GDgB6zuX1oIP37qDE7ldjoWrsDSxM62BiOPmFcc85tZTdqMLGRqfzvtQp1V83Oh3TekzNEBoP1aD8qiCs3VPKlH3EgDO0oaFQWSgw3Q9ChDr8BsXBvjOzBDshU0mm/je0uU7sMeiK2WzPkdXQFIKAlVgKe/DMHQsA1sOlkaywGAAfNElSD/0eSnagiikFPtPtwGvsORdyPfhn8mvwgzcH7QWszixKZ7MDZ85ogIKqmuFGyMBE/0j7DmhfJMl7jvPTIJXTm3MmPTODl1Shd6SsQ2Xnzmg0SJkPVL90BpHq6Wh9QhaNmiprssfRBaxdIGPyOZgkmZDjkplRz1L4T2dOf0yFDVvQ0FBCTZEJXipEqW@4eivXRrKyoRAkah5klPnelr6vfkAlN7e9sx95/8Z/z3MLHQbRtxQ2vBbVa9OfN20uABOMLJtAkqG0N2azWh0Qy0ig9AvfQsErLMSXbOFefeXQvg4kAUH22h7pbeJuPBsudOxhHX5dL709Oj85gaUTsd15tftyb9/wDzG/t/jvR2yHvDvpDHcK@zjIafRJmyXHIPjQTNFc8QP2JwbOZrEgRnOoQaOXaDXzb7JiIYETYZAsdYDd9TAbxATNIAlnQrdvkTnzqaH4NXZmSgZIhbpqYm/G9oJEfBtkJeIBeWg6WtKoLfAfhO1PfzXF/Q5JBpIsRv6uwLnGE173EliJTtr67vWEj0GwSCah@JgPxX0a4NVcIl@Qx4j0S/K2Noog2OJA43ylYaeagMTTKBZC6qHk2Q1NvCOrrVQu6SwW3nwv@Q0eP0p3AXIesL15ad4AMp74NVEHDhRd2emWhNzG6Do8olYtHQi0IJgSKZp7UlX1zazabCBUMPAVrVNhwPu@VTbaJCrCyb8lQd9mTkVTKMLZlxwrfwPnxnVHQtlX1lj5W9n4BMPyTcZMtVu/DUMV@ehbBRU5Q2T6KnoQ/D@RJjHwD0DjBOgBtTSXikdRkqAyrUB9JaIMb5URQ7OcBNTUX30MwNzpA3Pld0xahhbkSoAkkKOzVC8@khNJPxVDAGRyEz0LtPnbcx26nxx2ZlCd/pYwZXW0wUy642lKyL1CbRUrcNN7bYvELkvZbfCHKUwyzAqtwVOoKv7GitslzXpQmSKqvHjuJRicqayp2U08zwgmPHEpUiSvJnvAWTk5y9Q6IA@utA2n558/gVh6t9YiuCk0h6PQ2i@taopQAPoQ8VntJ4UZuqI7cj0n4r/CF0E0yacAPfcteX@idABATwN0cUI4z3tCXk3ozG9xgxgxdHJ8CKCJ1HPyvcBG@FgiEBzUcmtmgLS0rd762C8I@1sN@/MJx5fQz4JQJTLsYyIxnODdksAzdJW3eGsvAeXR47rNLJbdbLiWuHUoiofNErI@Rl12XXcGoqON/QYcreHSzIgP0ujgTLzrmfQGgf1sOJMWCSX0QzMoNrH2TtsMx20Qat4Q5IY52lyQP6hLY8eeSAeR4SK9J1LAvIpHD5GFya1lsZUXqYPgywHQhJy8iIgHYg@zrFEpJqh0wHKIgkPPVy5glrjczoHIBdPv1p39hHs/ikCTntPz/bw0kPBCDVJ1Qh4z3Tl3fep6ZNGAoUALiE@JPBvSLu3uT7coecMe/VKyEwjo@CoR@BqhJxj15PPb8ZlUQsWGAsaVrQPz7aVhMJFK29LRyne9ym/vEipxCtfdWmWMfK/CJnGRuJj4S0pBXgD7XImO@MTrpv/0EZ/4AkCn@NzD2QNv0H4uRVBEGGVWtNmurnOEH55XfBg6s55uEwVJpmdP0fxGqo87IV5UpkPpRNG1556zBA2gmx0usgSjk/q7ezXpHLsjezB0hzboaRhaseAVDx@X9IgDNpi5tx4FFHPmJK1Qbxk8kzVcHmrjb@mxgz@Dg05v7kxT@hHIfLYsYbIF1GLoGB/PWv39ivh7Gj1x9uvs7AaV/DqER2Z67V2Bbrq/tu6LfFxlPi1AAHKBO4ycztAxuYM@j0XVkjtNaccdqsDlfQU0HC9FWtja57u1GH8LJKID3hDGCpmVIw@9E6iZrcW41VtYPfLomLlzWLfKDsaseil6bdmY1xNWke/wFKIg8q9yWlVKmtlboFcHPizXk3v75Z@MPSDwFejnX8RxSxwj0BLXl7MB1mRSJqTPFuBC7sxDWqNpJYZVbDiAXWgUAtpZRKGGPy/XUYNOFUEokk4LK1yJMzIFig/mvUh1YMnpLOma9KRImuQogCJIiW7NWcewjs6sun@N3g4ecXOIXQYXpmMJOaUhvY5UXaASZgQMwZxe6yizh@rDM2Z7@7GjFiFgURIwhIOWLDOVUJILemLzldRzOtZyZ7AYJyLUk6eSSW/uTpOPpN7atSP2nDuO1l1zHZE@RZitCJvlZo9IW1zi43LfiOITYZowxegUG3gI1Vd69tk8SsRFsYPzrdhZPkCHdTQLzmT9TcUf7x7PfdwUbzCsVG00/pQi3NHla99/3@pAxzvrVxAJk9WrDq0YHVwyOkt@1EBFyORT6fEUIu6TuEfo0QPKYbs9oJ0@PmuJGj2AVw5k6lPIZQjpiW7w9tjBdWnaz0BHUqY6n/IXKV/gXFhLOsrLpy/RZRM/MECUip10YIdiC24wWBE@oliLfqqDboF5XIng6ZB9dpXnk0TUJxjFOEjjDrv3tjrLdL69z5AWPiTQKviu9nsgyVdYrNVZEJQVUsAUjyGF36OVtenq8b362r5AOYDAtemzd41H8CBNYWdMsQXYwD/6p84CZeCgKVkzNKPCE6FDSwPMBdBSBiOH1VWU/oYz5ni8ykdOI1Ag@DVd9LMla6Bz9F7OpzZWWfSWWMSU5ObZZmKyNKoSMBT/RvLLqciiLimuAMBhjKF@MQ8Q0EmMsMdDgZHTn4c4L4SoHCOoWMzjtISX5GMW@JDEfEeiygI7u1qJXFyJb3UY6VggIFjElwkQAZklvkgABTa6WFy0Ei/j@xOUAIFY8T5THIZCjkqYhv7IMQEpkV7ODFaUVl5YOcnB9HFn1wx99Pmbvn6b077mol@BPj6GrXQ@@vVVLvQ11Oz2drhqqCbQw9RbDX0EUpg6wv6q8HX/M8glUHMgVxLugaZkhKQM6fuFiQ5BywS9LfOjJw7QxHGoZAwFjw7j0nlSFZX61eGAtZCL@/3u7CJJRwboCf/VvVUxGwoTGXmRvJiQoz0bd1khJIk1gVs9dgs1XfKmQMMJeZyAfqt0Wrcv3jdPTnQlWFwulaPR2Jnt5nI5ZOJLPZRA@W2hKWnoZsOls/3r0Sg7vf377P1lltZ@TJk98tyC0qAdGBKYFF7GnQ04zgZxgKJYOg0EHrs3Dur61/2@HtCCJ5Q4eDBsXJJ9xXqCNqCh7/TyvsnB9SfBBvtP7CD275/Cn323NguaEoo6hoLaQL2Lm4Q6PQPy4Is@@n75J1UEDBdm5c0E@5ZZPPyEOwjGidFgkTOoiWYhyf6JN85o5FriA6Yke5ogi0qkwsmJXiHHRfCEEYmCLkYj4DBLODfDUXA@5WERndcRnNqYVNSO8rLHSIO6M6gspqlE64cEbCvQ5S3s5hZ6@1oiMUiY0vX@EWCZDwHtR5Ue29NUl@gULQxbvZzBwRNg9CJvxeo@oSIm2cQkzR4ujUSNRzfzozuc4IV6JskCKjKAhpd6sqa4T9zExSLfRxrmGIbEiS4KfFSNu/2vWxq/blm8mff7j1sVKaiCB/azVkSOK/u6BZHOAGgGyukH9MToyn@kYVqfRAKhWMDB0KfVdQcrdLCCYTzvFn@@TZVKJfFsurUlSqUjeMAkP0clUcYXR0eijBlU8Pc3xe3d3X1ec8vmJ3h5pF7eiSOAwRcSd69mZfgJ34oY4AbbPWmRz7LFZ9b@s07x4HDfy7ZKR@1sdgBPfMFUtiR/4M1T2SP60frBL5TJZLLPup@efXO3j79b5Xby2WXr2bSdHOwjlwEZStdztzpP24H7aGZ2aWzwLqC9JT9SpWd7mMpVVhUqPcLYnv0Eq0tBbHS97IZ863EcLq2xG11He@9MMAkKqPAqhCOqyhsYIj@2l2iOh9HpOuiAB/sN5XElP1Cuz2crynA/cbUC/qnKBiEgZdYbB0DjCccSOskNY/wA3rjsTNACfkMyL3fPMGz4O5x3JP9mf5AXP2xepMRmTmxaYjORoD94CcTmhfksO8TLRbiYfz1EcLSAbobCG5KgR/oDRS5GyG0YzygAEiGpcGgqPLkeX6LxWWl/GD4pw9e9gfGE7h9lEwkdMmGVjU/PJncwLJ@gxF3CeELhjHnM@8GCQkdqMdSYdqLijy@KQLbHjgBBy2MmSMGFJvGkDyrzmV9WvZFjbVBsJgFGstZfn9C8xxewFz2jmM58RJfCoFEKfuS3uDfuc/AuoY1fuP0AATpQYXUyR2EjyY0knnXQ/QJ@L6mbgmI89f5J5mNfh6Uzx4pB8/8pNCagT090wj2b0Ds6x6SPTP/E0D9e0ZpKcFmKtueTGUOrMr4ezYfTkTzzIhLhyPmt3fFMwhElQAyHI6gLqzOMDAWY@eDWoTBkfVg49Hgpei52nWeCzLeK08HM8MmRRoTsDymY279G5raZHSImih2YBwgp35Wvbw9HHpJ8rhK3DuzZJeZaoCTNYjjnczOy52FOnQjGbt9HOkOQyeU8mM/QlY3pzB6MbUtsnLnNmb2swrYFks@8mzGhh5PknJDAySebjuueQph7JIeEKOJ3hTyHMHp7tJTB5jy2OBo0GDSkairIBA04CULsRJR0fg2NVYSOAVd/xiDoKK8s3v5ppFxiaeVFTyMJKegC/EPTbGXqGKoFfe74EydhMKr@zFS8ICtd40Y7poNfWMkxq7dqm2o68nxQwHKJ7ePuNHAmdmhzmo4MgxOTPMvuC94XcT5TYg/2RpKXFuVf5oP8AYgVyJE/hO8Q5r3J7bPMZjxJpZ5ceDI4fkPfR1B4zvi@@FkbWVWelVM4@JgS8p1PhrxYRnaoIdMemDAjquT5DxD6I3sA@C1v7SWy4sVG6runWbP1w8WkvZm6mPx68YtJmMglWe2yabEhD7PViiXnCuyMWSv0U3mleUACzJ0oLibhAhcTcuvi03tJAkAkm2r9kG3/mgWELjZMczN7scEECQ0ZYpK9v70sgs@uoLkRxiK7YTwxN001@Knv8qaAvZX@4hjyC5P/AhZKqSQzPeg5sz6AohgguqAAFbvsq@3cznZ@BzShgbNIz5xr3G/T3vWlswBRwkN1Fraei19C3BAixN3Cs/fh5QL6ORxMMBc0jagnE1rIJVROc2rH8NkK6mSYJ6A8UDmFJMAQF9MvY@PhIyr8lgCWU2UpowW7Dmrcl8L903PH2I7t4boWjQ5hjkQvA/YRIRNqGiFLxlvLoaaaLkkKNsuI4ysHBhmBwPBmN7TdYuJO0lJYMzPJfRSiMWpmhHl9o3N0ZYqGZugzKUwln4r84Xcv//t/137emG8cbmc/zODvfOPnjb1XG/wID/Drhfp1s3G4cYDF9u42llnQgeHx5X//H6h/@HeAg1@WB/DP4a6CtbfcOEwXqcqvG4d78JDf3oZ2/@9//Rf04RlrbJjZ5lnHEoTYvqLIsT0h3oXvooq9ZLU0GSwreVxYEAZ7GIJuDj/QMWqx/SpHZroN6VVxg@4/w/7c90eRWzw5Zs3JVYgtGcqfAiQjrlDEBtIMUrlQ9IXmu6HcNpB5AzTFP59n9jzQAP4p3Tn8Jn3Xjeceugw9Y7UIBjDFLYI@zw@Hue8SvntHIaF8SvaVCImqnVxrX73YB3Z45zrzYTfsJaGm67hr3zqXGeTDjNO7Bp1q4o3cH2fZG2DJcX77VbaPxv0s@XFnpwQpPV1mfgFBUGYjAcWQnE4tMYMRcMfwF54xRwkI9Cf@mZTKzgFS9tTpsg0rnOEJijSa5Uq9bvHxMHYnE4jSKfoXBHjMQyLTamiR5xcTqFmrF0Riyy/I5UjnNRGbd@QcK5OOpNkblrLXggBDfUDroOpPpjQbUBAS1ZoBBC6SsXu9ji2/pYwnCRV4bhlPrpzRtJgg3zDoDV6tBhK6pD@LmWuhpIdoQUinaaFDWGNnboOKXkzQG9THgxbmeEUBn7WSbkyri0/Wviwrtfpe8QTPtO5p@pabvoURRSkhaMfnmSAXzkToxXhtKaKpcuZ08EgttmFozVMpsGYZ@oMYeDws1T6GJcjuUAQkUC3ojvQq04fNIl0YeOTW4Zg9Ni1yHjBjIwh@tFQJ4KzqWQZlJ2w3w43BAnHmTpwCeijzFXgYAVFUSVuGExKAVj6r2GEJhvpQmzqMpiIUdsSS29IE9kMSODCWUgAJho7Hm1rgg23w7uGDlnC0hD4JNLwkTGSpfoGULSqohqNASbW4cdTM2E7V6go/WU9f5gKiy93wRSKX336xs7v38tW3GDP@RPY2HgxWyqAWML2yAQZJ1ClQsvF9sZhIJvgVJvRabRKhx4HFAzh067o1CSt@fIoXCjCwXIJg3VJiKq4uzZUEMoA4czK4I4COkpolUqnvCi3sWPuiZ/4K/yUsVZsZDk3N9mj4i82k18bhHQdEUJqjsTN2Z3g8jguzTZldMKc@bCH8RS/ruP26gxdXoa8rsz00dOq6GJQwc68HVzp3ZNjaL5owYYDg89myQBrUa4cjRUmn1rBCWVQaHKpa9EVRwWut9gCdcnFLQJmPgcM0g8mAXv629DTF2ZGETQjzPGDEKh4haq6jOjsTd05cUTkrRxGTmdCGng83o3u2gnAH@yGAr9ROMPOR1t0mUBemxED2Wq1JFhv0SfeVC1wOywFXINNjrHQX03ppVFFrNckN89R9ZMkTLw79hHZBVRhHxCsGZj73MClVXKvqBRJELYTSmuQvYpZ/nqOTLMBJH2Scp8jLiYLmI/p26HmUy1s2ljClRykVgoH0@FQiDiDabXIJ7kiugCNKjxVKY8WjzTe@ksskXpLKA@xrqk5syWFfmgooapwzi/i0wP5Xz44tUa7APycfyhYKykelf2C//YRZ6/HNS3zzBVE9UUNABJVmOPK5RZ@pnzFECZglZ3H6kgBBXHzJsIH1SPJGClaqJ5L2PKlbobndDrgC2dWWQriyjspJgllTyAbyRCrvZDqTuRalQl9g49XqSrMlC6tpwSau@ye2RpMnQas@JCblI0BsR0GkFYiA258EDM8e6CR521J3UYxdPYnn6RDLskIFYvtJFsge5tm1lLmPLbYlW2wXcBzv4wvi23t5gy8vCzPHA7zx9Mt4I/145kj/WzBH5c/hjheSO14UcO1h7ph0Zw6tSBTRSUnt3BiOuVzSHtzpDQdDtA/1tZ/YiZylAaAFj@4ksykeJJ/Dvq1ZTkQq/sNWdD9CJ6Ht3T3jCzu/Izu/U8A1lx7Lzv/Uzqd/487vys7vFnCviRl5KdrJ8NffrseBSJgKv4gdXhR3uZj5pT3dkz3dK@BuGjPMf3hP079TT1/Knr4sYMYEPnDgFK73czNLIqXGcbUauFtkVAbiFGYFjOdKE3UvvBfbEv3RtXdVRGldfDH@ryT@r3A1oqc6ktXWYpR9XZ7VUw6WZ8mSb87DICvuCfdXhnrp/ZUbVqCPyA2KF2kybM2kogICucUfg9OmTCA/Bquvv/k8Fmde2ym3EmeG1RRo1gjzZjDFWfKlwioB6xNm5Dla0o6b9dOt/8VkGNs/ySg0QB6H9hbvGJI7ia6C4Vjxa9kZrTsIuyF1jhCrSHISsnMZ7e2zy5P1qxoltojsi/FKAh@1cbpkzEDlaB5AZDIC2mRkfaVVoWuuUi/4DfSdC8V3Wfb4i7j0W8ml3xZEXSoG60hlS4Of5MVAT9ve3b1vD@BaGfyDEzBnQfl7ZtX/Cw4XVt0/Sn2kTuet43kbWrIoQ8/TzWUElhHhMqVrKDMr4HUxk0v0P3jvJ5/aNrRsy6CseIZx/LbcQNuFfdntOf3B1fDHn8YTd/rzzJtf39wulr/kE4ahkvOnTM5aqLxvpJliNV9zYpaIJG1Oa1mbAxBomE@y1SRsCEnm80mzVShst02B83PM@Zj4fCAAQCLqxBvhHUnkZuFnD6ehZA@GaGyvR0f/3hxjzoFkqZE9vuzZYlEQ6H@dzlsCvcHk2y4QEkhEdphUF1bPqWmadCeMvHIiqUMuJC39p97V2WBcZfucSCQkSvCzSgcCaGzxi/oWmhaZXNpiE5iPvwx7YUsJ22T8mjK1HqoFkk@3d9pmAcj0gb4gw1/ZozmfCKZ@MX1PGGfuRxLg1nnMixzuIjkzFLigIX1AG6DfMVMyR3DKxf3V1tXQd60dH0YrAN8OFQ7RSvuxBVPfD90BYDAV3CPXHZ3i@KoWLEkNS7wKOhNkQsSw5jf2qO@PgspWPGSnyhDvhPtIOWSR2qGBiRBCEqPvr3RBMPUVNutKS7FfHw8bAONLcldYAaXji5VWCqxwCa2hoZw@tGlE6/HwenNOJx7TiYA5Wz4SlCM64Dft/Yb4vlaH0b@xZ0M0bLG1LQ9tZJwMzM8BOfzP5WSKTVQkJ9f2LswrHzLNMHMFufg@rUM5tfoS9F75EhugdQc7gLfnqi7gbjag7IYPI/0IlO@ZziEOZbDI3iewHfnsrZg6vyeFumQSkZbyY9y0C3M3svYMfYxTryKDreiA02sPyaVetFleCT6/wnHGnGOwB8xsdifbEOfzISziy8CnmYQbchjTpSxKQsTAODd/dAJ3ryxxKX/I/DoSU23xQNpQnv4rM0g0vqZzCliL3TG2xEs8cyeG8CGCAIczIG/GrYjYmP8zK7bN9d2FUthPb1WwjHQ5NKjx3XWvdQRyD/YzKK@eYA/R1/EVQgzbYRZYhaCWWuk6jHuD/LTK2Xgk1elg7p9Oh1KtdDooP3Q6SW6FhQlNCNLuvShd9q5n6Zl9Nbbtyd@zXc9L483b07lhdIGsBwciWTkrJzHUyv@UmS5hHNKbaSHz9AsSOfCNkUiEo0yPGw3ROK5X3zUFfTNoTLruaORI8UDKSLVZD@8HLQ@7cyU2sZSnfo1tTCtk0IWU4tjzGoQL9xAHt9NB9/9OJ@U5o742OhvBE/z3pvn2VDQp4WCz0qB8iI2YoggjgwGQpJ4i4gdPy7Xj5sd3FaDieHRoHKg/UOiQ6h3Mh/ORc3iQ5b/8zpsvURRYTh3QAuW7LL2EulmufHDp9pbwpze8EfSpmFBH/4WZA@LW8MbZh8o6bQnBvuvOAwSzUB@BSmhZRlBV0CuDIFcr10RB2D08sgFBUCkPOKk8DAwZ9pci@SKZGXqk16fMcMvy5hMpjSb5ZwZbTFoiebuVjNn6wwPReFMCWr4@rR2VTjHj17tKHdNYrhuLy0EHmAYlWLqWIRn@yuFp7iQkVNCXuZRYox/Dpb4n0Tj87mP43Zpu1Cuvq5jPcT3mTNKi@JQr5O/Cn27Qpyr2C11CQd/uVjFYg8rJaen1vVigUrey79FXtDDHfl3TVO3sdQ1TUGLqzHUtupMBaBqDDrYcQ171GZvu4EUd3qPorVo@qpXvoflgxJ2JNoqN4fR4VFPHtfOz9YuDdBHOh6FsGD6i5813500jXNNfrGDC0DpliYW2VGlTS/qkLMx18I9KjYqonFLGU@0T@bqMnLGCbomlxYsKqKC0djoeiC6WSlSIYkwhGtdM16rGLkf2JejP13NnH@NAC5/upov9uTuVDzjVMMdvgWNdU5/ues7A3L8wPt0luO1iAhg6cfjpjheri0mSr6KZpySi@mRewdtH2jQixChX6tX3lbKiR0P7HCoJRKseq68@vbrDWRfj5jSKUf4ZS2afiRmh1MomTF@I8gwhSSCYMgyGn9HvajBDr9o0TXJ4u3/p4uYHu3BveO0VdnPP9326SERWmmOQlr44RpKux8gJqsPoXfYndvc36xz1BWHX7@0QiLWglV6OMHEF/Df63Tt4YcgRvXTnc3ecprTWani5Vug7TqbQZx8ATK71tfFjTNVoT76E3CskexRvqWlGqZ1Pqse8yTdA6i/V67UPjchquMKX9mzm3p5Pfx/WFDk1bvAkKUirmEC6CVjXhj1xYdAqRhfYzf15ybW0YjGFeChlqQuDy@nMjroEYWJmt@kiwuDXV01mIlrZvZ38S5INd4/flWZhOtWx0h9HqKB399ApxDlrCaXR/A/nrlNo@1@SaDoL/k5UW7/mUcr2e9e8QIBpVr5vRoUWJD/dS61THl98GcFXt1@9a4FASC2sYQ@Jr492vPp2zwrfH45G6wRfX8VbrMrLUqJcU1NT/xbr5OV6pVE7fV8R5erralO8L52eVyJi8wzPhm4cPsiWTc2cAV4IAfSjEyqt4aSmQHQxtILi4Pgci4Ld8DQcbUZ936Bpib7D4SDDedLjsoZuUfXz/UzciRPbkmoi0MsLcSmeoqChWvLXJFqv6Eu4zi3eDlqUcOWB0K9JM2p6h2LSrSeJhhkOliBvW7xuFe@xXDUIj6QNjUcpRN@Asgg43zZXF6Grx9bejqstSRE5KgSJ5sqMmOfDnfNAsVvt3PZq54BgX9U9iSDatTLQaArg3Y9Z1/X@cMSgzYcRA63wj6YaRrWEKGdGdPnVEwpyQVjHJbLhFs2C8GmYDHr7h7OkSKq1MM7UpF1ZUWBZe3A9ecwU1c9Rg4PUxVNU4q2VCWw@NIWP3dHqkOXX9i85G1yCTm/R/5v@LhJ7Fm/dd8lF/PG9teZU/z5A5j3DHbsURjaF6lm58q5yhlfSiH9UPn6o1ctoEm5EtwZ58XtkCH1PbDKherrNWTewqgpcjLJRzF11TxTIMVdi5HZhVuBIkLGMduJFcNTI4Dn4BR7kzcuhk2J1EE/LBJkzkmFqrMBgNhGr6zwdM3OHENzOKj9QJs37Ji9Xx@spVuouH1k3H1MX89M/tu3tNfUf2/6LuPpkmWVjkbRXIUb8Z7lGiPbXS32I0ACzboDun@Qrw2f@vgMo/v1GkKxfXzl@yuj0Rw3iq78G0f/f5eyRlXfiKo8eWXk3pvL8sS3vxVV@bMsv1zKub@pc5V5LRC12n8HO0u7214r0J61Iyu5536IUP2ho9/tr2P7MYSPL6@cPHBki/xq5P3Pk2Bb8@UOH1tC/Ru7PHDmyR3@dBIeGyMggkoE0ih@q7lHswu2wewXaNQlA@ON9IiRaNCMoBNZMJ/UIMpmPbQzVyS9TCL9U1/tSRmOnHbR6S7O1UB7rkrEK7XW9DntvvC@dire1cvUkzoNjhUCe84dN6W1S9H2yBZZc/EjeN3FGs1mHTcuPpqqIBYJOgv6YY3h/7CRDv6SWKt4m27BsP8bVmv1l/XrmI3yfpefu7czF@HMPb1hSId5je65xoG9HKZXxUuXT2nkdBrbe@IyJ3nN/n4F1p2vpyCbOL@H@G3bQV2tglJP8xZUndbRnshRiBp@3kvEO2pqpk2Jp@iPXDlCjt5jknl@vmH7DbaS/po3049rY/Jo2Nh/XRvZr2shm4xpZsyyVK0fnr0VWNN7UPsSXoS/eFV4Qhbc7dWeOM1m3hIXXMKjz@/B6rOX8T7MCRnYIfzT82RGp9KD9Xi5HP4F04t9joS9C2uDw8PHoDCcqhfKjhocuQPsDx@dz9ou4MWKq8DHFb0rPNbb4s9pZmgzwIUM832Hve7bqJnnPwySB0irvudezrn6eQqlpcYz4S5CZNrUSOXXvDoa3KYUdaDnEB@O8VL4HCn0VKpMo3w0Sz7fsmLoFAx7bSOCH@zWN@F6uK@2EFiYlnhB3XkziN5P4vsculoG3c2vFAbjdSiJGybZiSCJELJgNHVA6ncYqn5LMqMnCpzuQCQkUPN6txyPGAzgW11iv55WS632ZV/k@aN5cS9CVcY6FFwk58YGvuk6ba@LH/IkgczSH2EOeI9HlEfpFEoV7j9wWoVTO4doiaemRPGvJycdpgaxpiQUsQfhv3IL/aJfx2InwuAGOdwzXrimjy4SNtfOIlvuROlzdiJlLsTDC1eIkNjz5BYLHU3vN5qjx9UowInGE1AL4jH3lOPE@zqeqcWz9wKl/ZH3oK8UimNh4eu5P7WTybs3awHOM6vuXJyBVLCC6GRenqON2uA41QoK0HU/SBfTM9SWxkBavlDLXTt8pZZ0LoK@fW3InniJVztyJ8wUk5L8PEjGGA8MT2Pc3sVdsJJpSxkfbJFakSaygACL/jJuyExKqX8vTYXZdhw7riCVRr5TKotGsi5Pzs2NRPWs08UXthD6cVs8qMac6y/hh0bc/RfCWonY7SP346JU3DIg3xH@lVZi0eUVwOfbS042Y3R/7B7j8gTlGtA9Fa8VRFsXLeMKqESo8TIP4ii2A3Q4U8WH7XkBDzonxb8AF8dS4ny8e1AY0jWDiCu8ak3rhZuIsQAfxkuZj16hWYYeXJdyrf6OdUhMQYnfK9WJHzGIUJy2vseepKzE@Y@CYhHQffIxsIdVMdUuGsXbeUYH8Grtf4OYkF4Soh1NoeCL6W@kIVt3ScbNSFm8rzTe1csP/FHHmxTjdaJTuauibFoJrRoLzk5fO4HoSjTGl0LdJ75GQOXY2Nqw1Q7ma4kNeM92RCzRawYhuf0@ujdY7Lp2elo5OK5I00YC9hdOVeizm/O1M7flVtAesxqqIW78Y7PazZCT7y6tkFD0dQqRbNBiRdyHdWtaLFEFCm8ZDkeccLw5I@/HasqkgMY5WLsN0CFLbmAZmFjUM5AKR7op0Xg9If6pFHdN1OjJtOr@2MD3SxLmlqWb7SWmN/wmB3I8Mr8zJ6MpcXHBljmIr2amfQqL3gxjLxOFOblfGgz8UF84klqmOwkH@YuqOloORC8/wABTP9pyb7OR6NDJwy@8N@/3wIOjPh99s442YTvfKFYDN/wc)

Slight variation of existing code (see previous answer):

```
              #     :x.methods.size     %6
Ruby 2.4.1    13          82            4
Ruby 1.8.7    108         50            2
Ruby 1.9.3    110         79            1
Ruby 2.5.0    190         84            0
Ruby 3.0.0    445         87            3
```

```rb
print 108+[82,2,0,337,-95][:x.methods.size%6]
```

Answer (score 1):

## 446. Python 1.4.0, 18900 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPZdSD4UdHp@RGXCVYBIJBvvEGAZLFYXWzVSySru90ACpVIJIBsJjJRmQkSKJIV3RqHVm3JHluWbFmW3bK8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsanm84djYBDLzPs@999xzzz3nvrKj@4Of/SyBF3ni2tO@7QYkMP2AdD3rxPREcmdKtnXLz6sax2GoHa8/HppO4Fe4BFEIsXWnP9b7JulZdmB6WeKbJumYtnsK/iohm2Nn7JvdOtg0QhzzlOw7htUFCCRwj03Heml64Jcj5K5pnw/PA2K4w6HudH0y8iwnoL55Qp7oYOmNjWOid/zA043Ach3wKiwkUVywlQh56Hq@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@lDwEbXpDh9d/8J8Q3XAxvcGJY1rJvAGHpANjdJcu/R3SSpx9Uieh0urqIaOYMqSESe5ES3x0Ah8zXhQv14cWwOqyy5lqyQJKBFlUkuR3LQfktEzQOSFLkMBmAEqqbAXSBqieQUaG95okFgTYXGXQAfaBAkJ4NjOZnF9Hue3rdsk0HvI/QiNh@IpsJTzhENWoZW0Fjovmv3WFCDZqRItBIpFEkxT4rwLJOyCjnBZHPQaPJwF@AGiGXIJgBSNci0rDJgs3YBdIy0uEt6@tCyp2EKNAmD5BVSBKhQHgWgqyWAAm9Nw1uDu4TQFq952MEAamOgnwB4wbaOkZ2ZMUfDKpbgJW1sSJR1Im9myfsDTB5QC0jNl0gRki8ARnKQBcC8WoLkwVPLQxYghJYvQME0uAuscP7AtO0Q1MBHULQERRluKE0R8FOCGoOaUGVEdBFusANHVYF1qsAnVWB9KrArVQWzhslCOKzCAlR/IceSGej@MSTE0lG7tFKgOwAwCtYCskkFEQcQoCYJoF/DjJKchsQDmYcyQV6KBQKEUVJIKUdKRQI4LssE6kyBfCFlKcChFciPgsCANhQgDgXypEANKABU0fKEm6sARUN/iKtBXECXkoM4OTBDZSoFvCEeUIwCSSqQpqqWZ4QLeVPzUN68RilaLUCNF8EP8KZCXlUgMyRjtQT@GLcEOCwhwReTWYYIHfEANYVNBOgTkAHVo1C4EBbMajEkaN0eDfQO9gcsZqeHUQvYdAqIRogqY/HgnUNsQlagllVsIZB9FahCoy0M3rk4eVsBIA0Eb3YtytRt7FiUGEPFLCXSD/VRMEObUqA5Gk2DQeymMjcXmK0FDNPs68Y09oSWmY09Z64FDV1Vyp9ngOQcuvrAjd2xb8@AxIacSpMyTyx75laibl1T7/Ysf/BqltccTaRj6oFjHc9Syeezc0jV5zwK6LHgVNTmwwaWAF1cf4CmWVnUIoYZuXEFLWRZUWj2OmZv7PRNoVyayx/1CcZeAJ3RLM0yc/asfh869hkcJUuLSTvXmXOe5tDWNOjzI0fELqbpWdDl3ybGAESW2LPM4JfLMxiaijCmegclAQFEOOg5ytjX9awJ6dw2aE8zy6BG8WQMrFEUuLIy8Fzl0kQmpcIcbVDMvSzJMcvGqyV@6FpOKkmSae6Cg/6JiaXzvTt0gu9hz4Z9NZIu9MUulTRmLDXlRL1pGpC2KBhAT22jANUxDR17bezDTNoHR3CsQCSQCMiWpnuCMi/tSBeS8Wln2/FQxAXJqGt6HsGwIBf7Wdot@@OOb74Yo@w1y1cP@nkTxIGebtlxBmjfogdUaIB30of0povZ7nnukHZAQ@x2bdcdrRBxoJM/RUD33VNzlvWZDKCPRjZIWuBuMkEPMnOqU2GdSvbzqbIMQSSMBxUOAGlSIKFYnmlQ3IdFh9gayDKLWawQtX5bQyh35kQwDRoLiCc@xnHGtl0B2cg0iFaXuuaJhC5MTFsUzzAPkeAG4lcIoqODNI45p7mIId1WRSoSHkU167vDxaKxPnc/LvrAQmHKPtWnUHs96G7NiT4EnYGgYA4tlwyBYlgNYk2AcoHF2idd10kGMZRTDwRfKHRcEipcI04Ca2iC6uRCFKzxHM009vg0Z50pkDLFVk6kuhLLyRVEidxVRDGH3JwDaywgInbHBmIN07YcSkEgQvmoF3jAKpkbF3ik2dTh9kAGHIXqoYgGDHiIWZvTMnzW2kNp3aAQUa41HR8UF18kFipvQPl9twfEdmpB2YFhQdQZbIMiAVEQO01EQ@QoypGAhsc2sYgxGhFwh04JyPOeXAKx1f3QIi/B0x6A2mGMPW9KJiOoCWsIoQLD7fWAel@aowGAIMMuMaYGNE@oZEo9/sDRR1zXpWzGGC0WdmZbNyGMg@rM7pNfJH0TkA@ibg@VSST8WTFGI1oQihDdYWKwowO@sCDGaEqRwyVmMXquK6J71zV9SjKudxwzAEzMN/u0gUBr681Y0hDFeqBVh6ojXeA/YSND@Jggt7QwmFRIC2@bDjQgA2gTmj5UItbsDumBnj4n3KKGohuGOQpCanEpU7OcOU3h8T3UFKirEAIT/QG3vk02r9AOBI3pZ07KRc0Jsz4KFRgdOW44GCBQ8SNWVhl/safXkocQJ1dS559jmIUcPOdX5GFEGwaqTZRVjANkKMgjLWOAHDFAnkMlcWhz3vh68cFtPnlvSIRenDbmRgHmw4lS7IT5WA1DgNu@Dkgc2QirvuCAQRccXgNa94dLILtxJu3uvKso6SKwxtcBHbqOuwQqIDOGi0EWfWhdUGI8RN6h2zEx0ubiL9QRsu3Z@BR2Z9CTjkauBy2DsZ4pHYOgVTZHXaHqnop7jLRI7ix2sNBxJLHbD7AvhAgjWwdawCaGLRV0Lh34BbAyploD53NZinMZpq2ewgrzd0o7AEZM0KM6jolqm@5NGRAoHnTSkNCUWJ4HzPAEuwrWE0VdikjpFHoGvdtF/orooO3@auIiUvTuuGNNrurvBjqKH/rcie6RHqruHoge0IhSyZ6fTFepO40558VL7iiQaFT25CEgDSRClad6vohdxT1gNIdTx0jxC02MzxJ@HPRKfBoMGJFJauQdUBiu5g6VCCSa4TG0a2qrkj504oIATwHdaE7QQxLRQ/dA2oBGCLpmudzt6OQcuIdHhMkuU0gixUQRc3FaptON0woRgXmZL6/IkvA9gxqEub4NS4DBaclpJ7GAwDfEBI3Ig4MkhT0sOlCZj/lR6YY5jh063kdSTCBJk7NYBIYOIEUzY4EIYhlW0A6Fltu3I/FlrVYDYgOZCthmNz2v10ZjoSJwaggsUpkkTEQM3MMA20YqDeXFwBcsNyA8AaXW6uQsGHjQ4qj9goNAgFbOQUqOEBvW8yPreNy9WtEOOmIgHlsdiE6WEfBVDkQA1hpqN2E1uYBV0H2TiFUkXoxPQV8jXuqKFcqHwTzTRyG4FmZlroZTmIOQVpeiiEUN3WYEvTs17FAkYCZo7IwbdSD7x@EQWMyIsqFMEDXaay2VAcHmwOCQJztH92thW2SeUsdyKgsOtmvoNnVex@B8FPfB/p2DnYNfbC@BYVudylUHycqVCtjVjidC3xlLOVGtrM/DmAG@274ZNkZcDMNzoTcR3MmcqDQ1oHOZROh8fPDFqygBSQjRQVMAM95XRBoWBoQurqP7gyudMOlnMpBkHCUKS4R9EsGMDZh19Nej/DwZv3yJlXc1U6PQHXNmj3UGIHKU9p0onoieVwSwyKvTYz0ijQuyqOXg/MbMNB8yys/bKDtfzQwVqOdI5u3H9/YOahRsOLom0CCSH4AspXtdEWjeHoMiviwMsD8wGSQjzjKOUjXN61IEG8YCgmd1S1bABwCo8YguEexhVDR/AHnfvVo26ioYMQVQO4VwVa6cl4eMz5vRuXxgF2eg4rusF6Ues84qdlraY8W@i92Wkc@bxVx5vtsyZml254HS6QToByK50QOvY19AF3EmRYZidZj9wwfXMu5TIRJUASHKmW8Tkabl2xxqL4JFkr60C3qaa5vie5Tj8YRPS1IymlEQDZ@qoHPh9yZWkJLT7K2kISykvrOzr96NAoeD2XQ8gyoNqJFjz@T1cIrQ8IFGHNd2@y7ZgDhMOowSBLFpZTF3@q5zrYZ0dMSiJnCWEfgvDt/oI@hrrJdUfaSx5pVWNl@pO/4pcGmloCGSKIYoKImGFz/UT3RA16zch/sf7EEnouRlOTbL9AIUzMWh6EKTMedKHYgACYlhfpYWMJ6WvNbaIw9hbl4QCx0yujjizsx7qSPlmKK0NPzSLL3jXsP4h@70CmmBCyMtMMyhbP/Rkwf7j/Ye7rzfDNR8fsGek8sFQByk1wFZSBwwvGFr3WBNE4uF4BLQNjxsXsAFxqCgRPNMY98Dxi1iEJFlYAXVsAnd1DvuwEn66auFOUVf4UPHYCT0EBsfCxpGBEW7a6My4rEJb@zPkX4GQTDyK5IErXww7oigtEofGq6t9yUaDzoG25YUVF32H@Pohr8sBmTGn5osBhviAtFhSscRdXvogvJCp82RNZAUA0/HrmyrPwBdGOfWTS8txhRMSyN1QUMAXVmKy0YZMLUBbsN3VE88I@23FLXE6FqR1ZzER8EWmj@EXeuZoDqloLcCVKSvWEnzdvM2mQKXRkhXgSSIuEEHOXyCfYFNQJCkY6eo50fIodwCR02RV1AcvRjjmC5wKSkv54pKIS@BWgZqGsisAo68CUM9MAZC4AoAT3B7dNxgjgp7vqE7PXEjNESZBbnvFhRVazxrNp0WCOjN2zRvOGPdmLYaSitdJdejbITh01Wg3oXiIe1GDkC71AikSd9kBT/r6tfZWVenratLpGA4CvscYUQe7oAg9dIFft0159seRpDmPaWNhbASBn4lLRkQsjEqhw/ElAQNCnpaID0J8yWA0IviIVAO8K25CGQ2mhELTNNgAPxDI6ldakpfl3DRWQu5xmJWcGhYHE2B5dFAyLQFDTMUedAERwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwlHHrD0EVQTG9DahY4A1DkfhyID7IJxzmbMxoaxSYZWHPDcET4guvDyJuEiCg2AL3/4WS@EE4ttIrmjI8UBFq5IdmFEkTxFFgB9@ZQEdKSha6Iaj8smnjoWKiIiR30F6LqS620x8NYID2ld/vBPLz/@7uXXP778@FuXH//65ad/fPnpv1sTXqGOWd/MNJuCmG20CJ@8lvlbe@qtnTu37pRoDkGehMz/X7/063/3G7@ymPcl6f74o6/9@KNf/ttf@fhvPvvoxx99@Sc/@vpPfvTVn/zokzdK1/k/f9U1/uvHbpjkKQ6NzCcYpgfJDQbQi94Hqa2xcev0jKytrUH0tbUtqIm1rS2SIVvwFOC5Bv3mFvhm4blFGuC7RlrkosWBBuuTJaN9Ih0/F03dGLSBWxpmSkuL0OWdnU/OyWDQmIjQzo95Y4NvXdDZJdoX4IwLy/QuVtohXTmDeX8Hum9mm2V@VdINqdmQm63mWarZzaSbF1JWaYGW3bbw4afUdEMRRQHckLekJPGsdCHFeZvQkBBINAbeLGd0wo4t5EFdmhH8PWsCPRGwSiCk@TF5ylro5A4OrX5gjgZTbz5APF4F8imOPc/Wh@AyGuR/8/zlJYs/Lwot6MiRxMjCgViIw14oaYymjC9yLKdNaWF5UtRjnQi9oRvo0rsiqBviXEeTXEtKggB9CPVhkGixH1q@AaqF7pju2J8fo1s6dIipg@vRYAzse3dgjTjTGLhA6dsAk8SzJIhknPAR2LRRFK1riHBjs0aWgVMM0BvTpTsWVD5tvXQUQ6FJn@i21Y3HsvOF0QsxTq1K4xAZE7L6juuZAiACYnB0nRJdBsfVo9ncfTpSdI1Xhr60C0C@a5lBltyzXZ1i1HWAFuaoEedCZvFBn4UoB2aXsx0i9EC0EFkNeGZX2uDo3KbrDYBdQmlwykaN62gYekiuP@qKwQSicinsoOY9mTYEQtop6aqqWjDyvUrkh7QAyB5A1aAW54BKGHkJCnimw6rdY8MokU776PHdPTbWQDsn7I5w3Kk9dLtjkMNCPePAdPpZsgdUZDnuEFipE8V/eWwfuG7AtGKwrBrJYEqmNRzbOh0juTqMcWM8w@24Nh06uSnqLPzY83VbZ4M2ke/Ouw9BNn56dFgTK3OBJP1keGPaOG63PFmGz/35mTo6SxlNp/iMMPn1PI/dXLTQEplL6FFCjyEupQRZMdSiqTV2DAOeKfIFhl2pbsThFBqOyUizhM4UlbqfBL3egrNGnY8F5CX2zDlHndnyygV1yOvMAuVZIFxruRBmHlCBhomXXK4MV6Th2HIOINaZR4l66HQBpoBD9wu@Zeo7W4GJ0k/IweIJ@4FpRxNwB@bQxUkm6CVtnM0A0R4FWbZG0oS@YoRzCZRN4wwVdAk6RLwqaEETGwksNJdYo82mYzkSThRx6xIJR4irtOGA1s1m9nzGQl3QjOngw2adzQij5uExpUdiY9frbQCxWa9GC9ZWBcOUksk4GIVK8wYxaDHpJPi1osZLGnw6JM3RKFXOl0Donqiy0JwU91rnScmnaOgRvtmc3JLV90EmwdWI67elvlml64FW4Ksa@SQpww77co6GYsO7xgC4C8lMFlEJ9TN2eq7dFdhcEtAaYVoIVlA4oR@vkgwXw5qWFy2QpCtUWVTkqnNrK6/BvVKl9esB5lZjxoBQfCDnx9mTc9I4zpIT0R/ZVgAiEsoTg3BVkXN13Sadz9I9T5/6XLgepEZ2Dt5@tyG3GARuqOP8UInV4iRa/gtam@eOccE2mHBVS2AFtNens/YWlheEHIhApxIg@wCDJVAlcUJhiajkY57PytIzQZ9LmVRcmg6zxExfiD1bDwLTYTTHJulWo5vNpoTJ1GjyW@HQfIXIdP7C6kEuwQ@yWCWHR3f3Dg5EFOhSyT2c56hAcwTREYSRVYWOMDlf@Aq51U2SWxgnjcotB00N1PV2GB@IugpEPzZxNgfZTt/0UuCYxikKA5zprBCNyKSxEEG4NskIKI5iYClQtrcYsMrS/D91jh33NK7xClB8hmIS0J26XUEpMy2OHeuF6EP3QgVNCBLqU9BL1NZTlJOtK@lw8dkQJ1hBqKYCIpSg0SCgM/HrEJgnrVaVzZRDWPADN8Quz9OqoKvEa0pU9TVwBkGGQgij116RZw1ZKLcy68tA0YVY4QJvVv45uAhhEbRvLk12PUXb@7WGzPLAZswY937q0@WPi9scKmSdGXg2MkuDR4uLKNOha5EW1xQtrliCRoashA5YYEEilpAIl9@HNEv9KecHrRejUYdUmpzFSFcR5eT8nOKQrKuE4hBMCmGVcRFpxcCYHrhQmgfh0vt5mYC21nC5BbbZJsdXYm1elEWZRycmp0snV4RR4YT6Rpo5EwYt59il0yGxqS2LSh4FwDj28Ni@HhNXatLHQlA6mbqQLVUszmfLH3Z69LEkDp0OCCeaqQMdaA5lXhAWdemAvuiY8/XoVxZXRM5Mv2eLN2nfCmYivHhNSKFcooF7nY61KiiUHldNRe@lWDhAClbFnKjMinh1/Q1ZQGy4mjR8/7ePuoDg6@gfQBeAI2@xoQ2dMlaFsAyzC1HRQh/La44NEI9tS6cIoKbXgTR0D4qk27FhOWg6CS0I0LEPcUg9rFkgPnyAKLkyGTXMOZsRi97LE1k2qeQAMzRWhb2yHoklRac/QFHrUiQw8cYyaSTKlFglmBM2BTGnKCODen2mokVDhBItq/fBOBizJ0izr61Ea4T3chQshJTzekcxJbZ@@4Yq9/TjcdcVRsf9WAItLAk7Kz0dHxKgow@nQ9toXF58VkC2Hjp6rwo267SkU/p6HVX4ztgfCR2qVXeZjTaE4Q0peDZ7rgpihfvfYsNqrFk2fbwhJYbQgVDC1QASrrgU5pBmXUGzrXemKF0MPj@VxTPrwHFqRiYjayumVkej1fFRk6Txy@XlsSeiwfCxTOeX2KrOUKWiBQ7Xeb6mVqE/soa6LajdOeNKpr1sYv5a0HhOj8bBLQh0H8KNRI4djzG2dW9muoHErw0jXxuQjjpHy3Chgx8RpSgq6ow5RovAZiBx@Sx9zE30W8sQFm2fEGLT8sbuGgEujlxBPW/AutiiRFz6OUcOorsKJ4Z7ivcqb38A6iV7Lu@7Xi7N1RuwIcE2bB165pWMf2FYD4cNX0OSp5Zv0sdyxB4vzWhg2EvdF4k9GrCbH4B7HQH7lu365JA@b0JQ3wMssOdy0p3HpaU7Ah28njffwG2i2fxZhep237ULpb6kw2NlrY@9HnL48P2mvCzmRYryGl4UCTquo4TvlRz8WPKOX1dBdNOehys554w3dKbLGFI4W7G6dCDc406F5SW7J5doTFFig3orEsb1K6f6NHr/HJ3EKtRGncRoSgVkkOMwQrkEhsBjQvPPk1ru5tS6b8aUroEtvq4Qc5V7bJvQLdHntSolqqx8zhiKLL85i@rZY3NsLlUdHnc@NMMO480Tl8Psrodj6Th8j1su4lAvQ2XujXKHPS/abmQaOk7XvV44WWReI5CnR6jmPgHDEzRcj9F3xqOF2lvQq5wDhprBKGqibnchF@jzeflK6TUyzoJk7Zv0vlHXYboZLm2q5WVZDkWPubmPBctNOpAWx/3QYs@FhKnLLOVZWJzv8uaMy9OgaJlfPLeSpairVG8auFyWHMsxgyk@35A7dlzX/jw1BUwSN7y6oGcKdJHoTTV2TXwJtz@Q2eCCj0MSnd6qYQXWe4RaIeAH1d2bKn1@cuaNalPA6cchTg0tWleNrDx1bH3Y6eok1Tl109eB4l5MHJ1hq0TtmwZp6PCEIpbE4qx2um7HtHX2mhRyN8Uri9qSth3OeuIsKZsbnc1kJ67wjtEUymp1QT0YmEOTWm8Qr/UunuoQvlYGmrh4r/KemKYhTfZMY1WAkQXN2sHnwmTsnOwSuA4oNgEuMEMFwcYljKHramQ91D3LfbDz6O35WfUwwP5Q75v3Iu1gbkgAV8gwxWlmXD44UCF3sCkZEC0EGwqWzrE59aP30ogPpwZU1Hi4stEZOCz4Bq1s1aLH612YM3AHzsAcsJXGsW0VlQIhBRRwSD1Of4CLnEajhcXP83iwXduexwOyGMZwXLe3NI093ASJe3eWxmc7q8PXa4ep9IA1PjSsJNOBOQY@7ruBOzIFalsV1MYhDfZcxXOiOdqfd6zkRo0WUBG9f174r9Wt@robjEb01R7ZY58@aFSB7lF9nTzRY4sq6PI31@uLL91hRwwdxXDFBZ3GXd6mO1ZgDHCTMKNIs@92jIH1ukyHBxNI0eAGs76R7oaYsYhwF51BoQf0elMR6aU273@Ir/1VlR6Ok7DOIDbc0L8vG4ui23CFkX5s@GzcD02kgkOfc62Lbdat0O3OlRdjK5gBnVuFEw9ksoF2NKzKe7h4YKUkQlfDz9hhuKhgJZVS4RUFVcGUQUBQViW7uC5rrolpGnss5Q2Gaxz3Iva8EpPhghQ6xGXNDT6C@wLpLKykWSpZO4Nx37/O29iYcxekFXys1sjpgtS5cVfoFnQnfK3CoGpLuFMN3m0QP8bmjRMD@RtnBmg4xRZ014JXG15QK@OVw0O2NfLZkwg9dVWwcIENqJlXZ7UYbqbL9cSwYrpmj43jo@l1Mhno1yC89qE/Fwyc6MVhYOTTrNNmPMlx@8CvBZvMAkdhV@lKSxfALK/@uHsT3n9k9nVcDfvACnDd4BKqoO1j2cKZ18L@0lj3rS@NoWSriA0337M5M29@2STalsB7qPct4/5CRcSZDBEcLjpkrwXyR6frdXE6sHxccBMbbhhzQZJjRIxU1wYReknIq4PP8bkDswbE9rItDb1sgNgdTXHLz5SabhobtgI6gBi@V2lRq5Y33ZiJ0/FwNPbD1/I80CU98wOsQ8bO/FMLgAsvgGuSgW4Hywdh50YTQZAK@7uZcXmSFfKBZbt98kFJJiB3BcRCOXcJ4dyBnvcJrhfxnCWUSNN@w7k71PkFJrf5L6BuTVyZ7ljBzQMYQYBrR6I3FoZ1Cu4pyAMP8Cluf14IwtFyjDyY6@TifaSv6aKBwg7dsWeYaIwPh5iXyEPo5m609NXC7fR4uMXpvGZjuDY0IzDYS5uG4TrjQPDGzo3cv3Aj96/gAUFz1U1SX9p7@DQ9X@t0gfDrBMnoCKmZaeXs9hVishyQpVbzy8XQkdh/lx1tc0DXqb4mzg6ev2NQtnzXXaaCPJlCR7GMmY@Hd00D57Jem8Yj96HruNC7jIDxDQ9MthF7YZXB8ogY7QFuNQY8dF@bzCEFu6JTYdKDPjI7UI/2zPQmfQsDfFcP9BVdCx32oipZbHotTVh2x/Q@pONZc@ZVWuNihu6bE6oGrCYM1taEwDCY9IpDTQttYWFywR@5rsOelHvK8FIe3swlgLXTx5vP3oq42ntB9V6qSi0W9fEJW7pgdtlJAavK6pkd12bPGxbEOBabqNY9y/SlB7jxnLoVckQAacq/kVcUb@QVMy0GJNMT3aczx8u1ghlIZfI51qUMdM9wcdImNNywZGRut/hr2HG8gJzNZncA8RPgTLoxDs92fF227GFnSB8rFYC52jwwIZkurlQ7nDqBPrlemWzwJdxfPrfMKN6VHbElbNQFknoC2kV6uQJ3BXvWiD4o5105g0tXigiOZRovdRxocileZsOrC/5QNukRNa4Ybp1rLnQgVNLpNuOlLWZx3RQIIrYpBAMP1HApuGmENjrjYsmQ/nho4rzn4kTCSpHT9Qe0sO7yKd6YiXqmEB63BjwjPnqNyXXCzkqJEcHD//GddyToVNuFXHTuA7Co108qQ@bHnhO@3oTSnrh@0LMmjyHfuLh8FdvAYuUhCrxYC0DTxqpCQO05Y5sNCPTnFv0Mu1SNEujhuYJgU7YcmILpnAj0FK7J9RK5bN@QtIOHqgZmVwg3oeNgufAg2kIUBwvfS@b05nkgrihUJIbYSSEXrjFchtzTiAOA/OQGwsinb2nkP9l/8PhIHPnK0n5oZ4CL7q/JZQu72tWSPDdK9KHuzU3NsbVQXcsPpDuHirD7YF/EACvwzUbvBXjh5NLCa@VQZHSQpqSv1F7Q1wyWC3z3jx4@yMx23JHU7sBzh2Z63nv38DCLGxjeOVzqPR/7HrSOnjtZGX1/T1HSS8g33Ja5iksuSWkVpCMTtEggxvvsUIzXClGGOzK7R9OR@S50ksip/TdMvrCykI/0E6uPrZCUVyKKNlRSFgu59Ny6X1CSTS9@r6rPY2uE3NKgL4m9Vq6QQAlBkzxtuZRw0@T0VWmFyOHk@OeLpMjXqXX@KFdJ9/@pGVMUZRWeD/Ue1CvJr6ysxQDLpjht9@QNZkPNUBkRYichAKoSrNcuVi4KQ2DdEj5wxDx0BGNn5cqMmwDEzoWlDf7UdKa6I6C0FLqM3FjK@MCcm6uJF4uc4DnPS6et4vXWJGVQY4TmI2/Oa3f3zn7kccDcQ9vbj56SJ7oPGs8SiOYcxJlk8aGA4zV4fNeqgYv9rgecmvUT/dFyuq@QQ93rus50MtdUcBYXuzp6YmUcB200kGlbE2sZ7zbY@MyT5StBojTYCnl3uiDnzZ@IEUa4/MqvK4os0/NO8K3IzHqFgEkKTfoUD8ua9zraj0nfwH5ZBIf0Uq3qgTnBFQNslHKZcrqUfxdu4O3F9Gp2eZNf6Qa/3A3pXfNDR9xModwAMH@DH8mLsfcD1z4duOKu7pk3oOOmrJdvyHp5jt@ERzDT2avQvFpoxZXg4WspvR2ZgZcbDdyOlVsQkRd3Tq4cbg90j64/6Lvh4nlmX57U6ThqyA/1l@Z8Ez6e8QFzMMYl40sm0jogiJlO32InrpE7brBHbTdoC/HG0OVzzdbo7nh0hZXg4fRXuNN7oJS5pz65g1t9ZvLhEuUS1xYtd18lTJF4hAkPF7x/tBMl@vhQUudSnOXi/ScLzrgZLnh8OOfmmZPJKm1LmKxSXpb6zFJ9dJRbSHaz/uzkNfsqoGcDVhe/V3a5jO@8c3i9daKmMAiGduTzju6YEZyuG9DdUfE43GQ0Gxx9b0AJIOJjSxZ0QS9iWQDDl9ptPK2k3V5FJUfm@3RgGfpKEpgTFOuZgB8eCmROcoMg/F4HjbKyAbjHMdc@HA0sZxJahjN3XOtGUh/6UYl3yKHtnpJI4ZlrPmGPBVH0E9O5eVOTUNZu7pC1@V53AU/s1P/wtQpFd1b03ndMz1sW5sCQ7kWWd9X0khDvHEYBlvnu2i4Oknat8XCZN42aySzz8hYa9tVI1jIPPLT@eOB6zjLPqGIqlTvmStBrN/gNp6CtLfPo9HrLnPd8d5nzw7EdWCikRZ6P3DG0nois9rxIeqtv1ptNsSLOrHgGrz/w0vMuwCmG7tgH8c6y01eDCh9awYLjFXxTNzwE2HREx70K9x2XfNGa5XO@EC9XYumdezOfxXHiMc4U0t1xM@OqnVKjqfZa8n1p9allOeE51vCK7@x8pX3PdZgtPT/vE52utATafd220qsnQtXXzIQim2P@5ERb1sqA4d@bx@i700ksOT@x6V7d0LarQgH6hpEOvxHh09WXijY3KMCWjKxY9jZj2V/aG@rG/JDjwiEL0bSRP2Pic5qFd/jozs7Re08ehPYv6sNOlEJ0Lrp6l63aitdoXBlGoSfHS4f4FPyBDn0XHUERcNv0lRm093YePInY8QBEckAlHu42N9AU812S6nq@PizHEuTDaJ/SXWh7aJ5xovtT0xXGcaFYf7dMzV@5e@Dq4VA3h5470ulabTwyg8Ox10uv3MiqLld2Dh@sYqvvRMU8fPvhO1@6N9vm9MgaEllU4X@lZYiKKF91Uq87adedcted8tedCqJ8ReZbIQ2KpZs2L2ti@Tps5Vre1esZVa9nVL2eUTXO6JyTfN1pSYpLsKXIS9yuhVPmskFXpmrXU1Su5165XkYlygTbuQ5iyvy3AfxseEYVO@mB7a/3xegDDqmUA71DevE7WvOHBeAJ2ql1PEF2nR4MAGHPz8lauBkfPPhoe394/AAeNGk5YxPPD2Bf0glq65BMrabky2QLP1JVIYpM08Qv@5XZeX5RYg2yfhZura9UlAuyViN8hSfh4Qbx8dzsiGkAjIfjQqGIcKyQ9QB81qON@YR@M4WcEzrwKxh4BinYRGn@iJJqeHQB5Gn97Mn@k73Do52jp4cNuXURHm0QlcJxILXoAJVbWpeHwod4A4WbHThPj9SwITn6oQwcMPajchH8RtRi0WoLRZsVit/COOtnjiNJ9HQHSbiA/Ak8S436osQLTgx2VGJaQeHBHhV20AI9LwLqiIHmaZpQaRUiL0t4pPs@FCv0v/qZNeqLn@mr4If6MOHwjHAQsPuu2w1T9E3y@itK8d7O/oOnB3skyuCMak6tbjColfPsCPnw9Dgez3qw6TEoyTBKEuqqVkveSwJikmKSVOh5HPT4djxpLhnTA57kEcbeIKl1Ch8wmIwrRfpvH0kXSRF3iaQhbDLKVBKSBZqnhIJn7R0BkZC7B/vv7h0QzP/eXeqMKEIQ5AiPDPjLH3TZB1CiI7qiTxR6w1ChhNryXatbwRM6DJMkcooaHvPTJXg8HTvEgpgT@jERSnl0NGvuo4VpemwSN3@sSHTWxuw4EKw5ygHmY7IPldBjNuIvpMQfeuI4egwg0PspPcXyygGPaXqIGvsgIzt6NQZNSS/62ALO9oICTIUgy7fwkA@sh5479q40Etx/T88zFckOfr0RvxGp02/5QGbHTsDOgwvPiEoAhYoxr8qSdZpZ9uUffi5gcnMNGknH7FsO8R0LZN6gQj4ECsaZ1go7BEYQ6slrUSLQFWoSUMudC8g08iGeqE@E0R4e7Nf0pMtf@xWpXyVgDsD8SWieyHfA9rXQ1gPz15n5mYQEKiWvffAlzst8hvDA17AELCNcz/rZz/CDrnxqXVGO295JJpmXq/BQqnmSJ7fWm4Kw3pBr2@s6IDJ4MWlCc5Y2cifm3UGvu9@XmjwPgnFOkjbOzs6S9zaeWM/ypCB0LbXwYjK90Arai8mFppReHI@UQkN8MWnxpVr2uNVstMiTJ@@/ar9K85MTOh6aAgLbfcwrOT5RKZOzrYKWOC7jx96ghMfkJVzHPYJ/an7ZnTPraO70gG6TPEk0m/j1Vb7IA9tLtuBPOcVzuBjPaNTFurjVevUq3dD1YDIllmWN/G4XbndAUqqaPiTQ1G5DI2IRJNKkb4pEuPLDSY9Mdsx@f7ynT63xvWBbLIolUZ1jTJsPP3gvvKrvPX1KyFPy9OnLgxVsrJXJpAShQc2TyPEByKrZCam09XwCP9f2l5@tXWTPnrQ3//LjoWSu4esxvj65eIjmQyV/a23t1p07uVxWVVVmfvLBk1/c2dnJ3c3mnzTyWzlBXtv8iz9fW1PVTVVaa/m@0ko2jo/f51U5x4t/@f1k@8mTL/l@XfuvH72qK/gowuOEFEkZL40oYMRnCW6F5PPkTa/Ey4QCV2JKf@1E5H62RpT6VvG/f/Pxi0SQqKvSex68g8SLRKGUYEYwgE2LbCeJemITgxUuElOpVquBsfjf/z3Er78DcNBnugmPej6CVZgm6kKNRjlP1AtgUFQV0v2/P/poLofAz4CV1KBFCqXIbRsYYqPB54oqv9WCa4NemxyejSTIkhSFc4JBYLpEKd1WbqPFAgu8HHjhgFYzgR@sfLxNxGcHGegTMuK79TXp7qYAlziSFEVtKsptYL/CrY1aTYB@hTZbTcvfxnMr07Q37LuBS8zb7y1ciff@h1xLwVTf@@e5DsiuZZiem@UShbXt53frdSi5Vtc26hl6hc2NtrxiiXfdbeA6R4OxZ7n4DczqA/yaS52XSyqfzWa3D9oQhUwmiExhMhHbCIKwL2wn2CW2CXPBhh06MqqEq448oUVidxYrss7CkefJBrSW1vPV4RJ7eP3Vf/yrb//VN@nv2/T@z3jElNO1etIGBDqBhlOHa7tSMep1vu7xZ02014Ha5EqpUpLaF83URqPeOgAB9@3zZF5LkkN7mm2reDXTzQaNX6fJ1sPk0V5PzJzrzKU@7xZ6sMDUAd4hpkgiKudcuWKsEXIlHJeIVkcJjZN6S8AB1prQUAr5lsBiNbahcni1WObbrYSwPsW8t@pqXn1MtuvsIoN1n7iYG00tRAUJ81uflW3mM7PV550S9ShafRbm84YL81SGkvlSKHvWo4xur1XWSpVCRZXa9dVXdRYDLxrUNM0nfuIkEV9VEtJhhM9ETJlzbs/mayKuFhIRMFmI@5pwXKJRa7TMFrSR2f/aRatLKyh8NTSpbZ5UgT5UTVD7bV5WoLVttyN2vgXXGvzoH67Yis816hI60yDXrzVSUTZUTcrfKuyp2AdfvYgnNOoZyiOFVj0jIq8UxCuBOOhViNHpdF4aHZBRdL2jG7oS6GN9ok/1oDPuTDqBMTbw08bkCQp67RABnubm3ZIb4UMUElpeWU/cRgrX1DJ@JRi0lFJJK6taUdGKBa0oq6W8ViprxZxWLAJArahq5XJOVbVCUSuUtEJBK5TxS8wQpgBhNIRQzGtljUu8aqyRA8bfJiQTXc3Ma6@nIuVoeFGDi7cguJMEiFBj4zjLJf4ZrrqiKmQDukkZHiAbUiNR6Q9KuKtbYz/LkQSIfWetVxuNVxtkvraEMM/wEtvbrYxwcdEAc7Ua/jfrsbFKL2aCorYuMpnNZ3WQhp7VGxkA@SwEKQqEAhXbddLapF5xamFyof9mq9UH38zI7yPJCDQTLyATmc3GZs3dpbdIW6fQglQ2F3K@vU1JbRti1dehW0hnMuuCsNYA0I2wg4LASJBhEQESBEuBKHN29nPeZHMTmMzF5kX9orF5cbG5Cf9N@rwI3@AK3hfJnJssuNub1BL/6Wt2XSz6RmFm/i3kU82GVG9KzZBXtcAuSnV0EaUmGOrwhnANTS21sHdEOUhs/cv8i9nZM3bBLLdEyDWX2CAbCTycSUtscInnl5/@r3g3Lz/9Icq0BH5mhUucEcIlpI0yoW70VQbB7qFDHrLLATPekRVd0KH@EB0d9nBQU5ak5yKpCFRdTimlQlrE7r/t9tq4@1UkzyEoBNvrm9CIIt5LeLVU4NsZZaqSxCZfKFJ2@wvXrmQy@a@eq@VikmnjuH3zue/7D@dyOcsnBK6qsiIo53V2yi47Bv0Xll3/6hdWXVzivEwQRynC8MIlgIwSkgRaJJeobw5xLSF@QkTAb8Gd1N4Xnu4Iu@5wpAdUXcexPBAVavt7tXK5jmqUuf6ENp6NuxvwVOC/twaFIM0eBG32asYQRPRmT8urTdRa39ZBewdGJ3Re4O/BS/yRIwN/By/wR45e4u8gwB952MHf0Qv87XTwdzTE350X@Hv4En9P@/hrfkHTlCq/rp90J134T16uT9bPKK4ySlm5WJ/wDGeJrXrzC4BOP1kl28kvNOioUL7caqBvCzy@EHjTil4rV0c1tTqsCTk1V31ZUwW1Gn4xw/Wz/tTP4hJQ08CaMI0Ur26pfLrKKEXLldNfYOM0lXbNpoMuJIUfIEm5fjoDhhR0Yuko@CshBCVafvTxwhTbNVxR0zhEopXzrifoxPLhAQ4Zray4XvKn3/j442StlhSS9KD5HLgJ@PVqeIBDo5xV1Gwxm8sqpayShXLIWaWYVeRsCfRKSc2q2Xy2kB1mX2a1rAL/VqPRftZQwfYSfircuezLVgP4a/52sdVqvGzdUsqtTE6FzECWcukvABqIaLIvWVVHgC8uUSPryroi27IhKx2lAwaLyB6RB/JA6SpU2ZRNIk/lKZGHrtIFkwk/GUyW3CNyn8iO7EAw8AVT0JYDNPXg1YdfDwB58LNwCVVHkQ0CCdmokNJvSCltjCmT8zZ5e@D6QXbU5BokSfjn5vPnz3HAXixYLfykQIN//rwpbbTUcomI2PbEduN5M9nimzweOKuWc6QzNdeaz3mQoGSetVF0IQnfbyRb1YTUbEqsBgH1lLYuLtrtvUd3220Ju/ImMeuZ7Qz0Q9vbNeiXwtdWol7dalZoTxf1dglpc6tZ1wQ0FzLQaangRu6bQDpZKfM5rxlgeNfXKAJaz0@fg8KWOkW17fQEXqeR4b0mPNpMoaPe0ul7zTkrNcCFYSXpvSUQFgyQa8ebxsIZ/EH//ef6W/@y/g@fknSq0Uqnzi42U/RK4y@dPrs4uwif9XQqFVpSm/BDB7BjlLOLOhppoDMwNVLpVvrigrnBM5XeZADraZLarNO4s3DQ7SXiJGmy7JH6H/MmcWFS4dVMVp/zm5uecd6sUiaak8skwT8H5UmfTY00mxMZmEMnOghbcMi6fk7HkdNVA78yt95pKK2/@D497HwrTQPlc9WqskGYRc2p1WoushVL1WopsqynUuXrV13eUgqg4uVywGKrYNmKwMpghbgN8ipDaqQJz9bt2yyRknp@HsHUcoWMjFNS1WqUUh6SNX3doO0cNL@z/cf0oHBgFPkEQX4QDqqnZPqhgRPdTiXX27XK5PbtVPgx2a2d9O3balk@P1fkUqZRQg4sZzWtmBXK@VajMhGh/x24XZ9OOdwqtJIk7XqpR/jhTwCaEhRyS61T@GXgwGquiN7A5vPA0WX6K9KniuwedJ1WugEchHU87XZnbNkB9DTtdjp9S9GAkWtlKGKsNyb5ZJVPnIF8VSpaPbK23mZMja@iD/mXciUIsBnkK2cXCUpkJJdPp4Azp0EEv0jgz0MmznrifD5dzcly4uyCZ4GVcpmFTpNcIVXKlMNfbS1N6iBfsh8KyVomt1Hc2MbRQn@y4kI@Xz0za8pF7cys4BdwLqpG@CVI3GNt3r6tlaG@S3KC3B3jSQ/ZJhd2EjWQNVBUhUeTSyYz5NZtDjege8lKdZsSnVLKk0SyyhyFJHQ2pFTOKJK6kVdKWDmc1cOTE0De4hSKnDWyxqn0jQ@uzFC2ho4JLjE/bHDjn@vCRbqkQ/p4kT6q9cQiNr2ITZg/fRpGHMhlV@gbW2lcOhAQuZjxxaY1tLzGGlaSPBgbFg4oPnmws7t3lFU3BZJQ7@3sZtXDp3cSClrzMzv11tB@sLdz9/FTiPDkwd7O4d7b@@/uPX0C7j45nV1xnxb1bHEPN2daYj8l73Efei9109TNsWm2T8fj0xfkQ8tqW1Dl9hjK5vY94pttKNJInxWvCrdh@fqHH@reiF7k8ntfufzeL13@/jcuf/8rl7//7Z9@@u2vwP0DuL/B3t/443Ienz/99Nf/8PL3fh8c/zPcfwb3Zz/99Lc/Yje1/wju/zLn9qPwngvHbg5gfe2nn37z@z/99Ovfgft3w/s71@9f@2z5/e0vr74x3jf/8OYw3/j3cP8RgxWF/cbvMTd8Xwv/eyzc179z@Zv/gf3/Ivyh8fcvf/NH@Agtv/qdv/gvlx//J1Ut/cW/vfzyNy@//PHllz@5/PK/Vi9/@98q8vzjDy@//Sd/86d/9Dd/@m/o/wf0@Udv8r/8zq/@9f/21//7X/9peH8G938A02d//Z@gGf/9n3wP/9/8k7//s@/h/3/5g7//k2/9/df@Z2r4HWb4x9/9Y/b88cdf@fGXf@PHH3@64vmVG5@fvoH7p/8MLm@ezzeB8ybl@rwun/5c@fmnYGOWCtAAUO4vX/72V4F4fxO6qcuv/AA3fMC94v8DVaFhfsBs/x8wqNfLjD4ymOD@1uVXvkHeRyz9T4Al@JP334fe6f2wY3///fdDDH6CfuD@PnVk12JE5hn5znw@IbNwUA3fJaTx/HkLp4wXQFPLTz/9je9TW8Ks1Ol0IPb6JbWU2QC1baNcjucJNzH8V2OQX5j9EouQ8iXNcZxqmINPkIstJPYJ8r/L7310@f1/ffm937n83tew/xdy5exOVlBeI/ZAwPwbhMOAhTcJhwEh@XaGjpcKGTCb5xLuSNo@J6QK5dBKWnMW3JR6vY0K/Ag8KpWNs6yw1SQFVuILGhe3NIFsqwjqrczWmkQUPattaDoElHIsHKk423IuU9zQdYlrn0u4/YmckzmjpLCQkhriknnhSi0phCwpauy1HgGIi8ElMpjdDJWINiI5La@RSSYsySScmkd3CDTZoMYJYbMpE@o94SZ0Bj/6z4wTjmSokEQv/MRVZKSGMF40@1@EOyxIHtLKzCZsqPRImOC2wVzowgaaeA40KToXmpnU6mjAuQbwugN6S62WwYg1limwsvzVS4TmJ5OpQeExNouTbZcQxOQOhQIxaxQPtQmLmEF49QgnGQ6daG4ypdpdSLA2uYsOGQROwT5/XquXapM6gnvFkJKZZO7QPCGwWmZSfwX2GoUJ8bjE3VeQlVItk6mXMEEsJKujbJvVVJ4WjpYdZ9VZRcAbl7ZtbRNyi1dKPJuxWkOEsdD4zMxCY0CMcvCcV1T@OZ9TZR4CNzMbYdnoPzLSe4Nif42mGybJyo4pr1FgpP1843kYkIaE1ARBFEUCNy4j2SLbZItjWMtkaGbglQmRSImFEkfsQCimuAytdYY2gA/O9EOgRFVzVdBPqgSdPIPD74bRtUkytz7BdWdnJJSZ5fBjmBecDmFyssadnevhurR1nVyAU4HDEDTN2sbnvjCziLX19XUuUec1/jGdf89IEvGOK3R1IbQ9qmlVCF8o8@hs0qWWDIsPcZ9DlqPmKhaTXH70/UROLia49ST98DBhCZFbGXZvb2@QW4BW@p5zm9BFfEJGc3NugqFxM5PhVUi07oJtg6IwQ6Fxz0iihn9wT1Byg974ie5ZfpbLUsaXhZdYS6A3efz4cZhf6vCsxmWgHaqagnacex2PxxDd7OI6h2xWFLNiNhu@RfqmDmJoEKlv@BbXEfVkXiNUiiX84qhjDBAv3KtXr4A2OMRFZd8JQiOpqbkS9SSUDCa4vE4fZjl2HoNtT6NVvGquzLGhFqIUcoSkKEXAlSa4XDUFNJ7m2Jo3Rl7RlUqqpVKShoQaE1MQjIEpKMip2LpguvOK5IsLVsjZvBXHTtk0Ai7AiBfksvylSvl05Ln7mOw@fvhw79HRqFVrQW9DP3Frtkeea5i@n0LPnUd3Gf2q5UIaZ7ux9EcVFXknt1eRkZAz@3cP9g8rhOEsrLwULUmVrl4IMVNWuMRo9N5mwsPJDM/k8QNPLn@Iz8oMGSm1rEHURJ1LGCYqaECp@Ie7Sg7MPhLwQ79/x52QlJzl@axSQLU6jcsLIDu/6I4JHuDITo0A/oCrJ0UoMea8fibMTeehQ50cqBwzCAo1EK1cigxFZlCKBQzwmH37TOPqh3tHAPnoMVFUWSQHbseCTNXfJxOREOACB@7QdLPCBY2NPOnIGroYwsbJh34wWMfvyfJNmZ9D0HqDDRmpmgZPJVfIKvlia23NPhMQTpMSzRmuDb0A65mAOHkLLsK9xZG3wAku4YJw7sh0SDgzsv@4ysgX9yOTFOT@MPB4JQ@cIc3hBFAIjxvNX1XEOjS1xalULrH2wQcBqdf3Ht0V9u/h6MVkQKKVpYLVFQciJZ3u2DOpb5@QrvWuhXslxK7lj2x9Cu0YELZRB4wEOM@duLi46AHM/XtEravUyuJ28XlhUJcOmC8mOkeAR/e4xO1owIYr3q5Uaq@UXBHyVqm80lSVAwduQ@ISVm8NyI2uDdqQ2I93ajlFzijhLI9D0jzPV33IlKaVpA0uofA8vDRN42gbIlzF5AhdO/ZKrtWEkM3nFLp0jMNj7fVJTY2vMOzk1iysJrOw6AMepB94RI78iswvtEU9AxQFF1PTL5tGY5jy7dsaDltpOTkuO6GoIRdQp@taTqOVdM90AqQzgr6tRK4YTk5COVsJzjYD0q2BOdHEgtN02eJ0/Lq8T8YQspADpnhaURW6TrySU3MJnmBoZJVaSeYSjQTwAK7RAl7w//qv1eBak3@5f0BLo1HjJsBL5@/QGcPQd3hx3EP38ez/@PFw3nrjf/jYffjYHbrwh97yITL56uxfrS5Yb/6HvBXZa7UKWQ3MCdAb/HJyHqz/@O2P/uE3/@M//NYnIl6hLXb4x29/i7n/7q/j81vf/odv/dI/fOu3qMuv/cPv/pvQ6x9/9w/IXWAC05c60ubl1z@@/PSPL3/42eXH37384Z@idf7/6b8LvT7@1swRzOhy5f8t8re/9n/83Xc/@ZvPPvq7b332d7/zJz/@6OtqSfnxR7/yd7/z2d/82dcI2H/yo6/@@KOv/e2vfPzjj34Zws3/f/KjTyKvL8eOYAaX639wB7jc/3/deCGDxtUedAHDZnjOZ53uRWgo5VxrD3hcg7Q2oyNA6xB6k21xJHiGS41HApQCi7nxdd@0eyKu8K/xm6O6Jqv8ZniOeJ28azrYh4Tx691a1zXoV8CrXdHCr7HjZj4WL5fjq66Dp/3Vohl9kDTSZ/3aKd2kXzVrfRHPlfEc3YboHbc7Ff1gCkKi4dquV0uCypsEOftdy7UpFYN5p@s6KMM6NRPULJxs2NK0XAXKJ47c0ZaaLwpEaCgyCJ54K6VsF/pBbwv634qaXTO3isVKVzRsU/e28pU8ehvx2o6tvFzpi@8/fHA/CEYHIDGZfrCVK0MEPJsNT1HaKlXyeWApPJ9p0BRb@HljJmAIa2vQH5t6V4A3Lv3wBbXUqtD0a7VkcktTVEGpaHKJCws7Q5hTdYScUtiSK8E8GsmebTmul@U5/AprXAtYgQOlnpNzmxK8CdQ9rkMBcapOdsy@if0RrTllUxohTYARgupg7IAxvyl1wGiBsbwpWWAc1zVF3pTGYDTqOQVcDUYlWBvE6tYgTSxZBrOdRXLJDpSzUL6oOK5jXnCVrJ61zmjNVXq93sXGWWZmIYltuvZcvbL2/Az0tjOBhYPavhD0bOcstlaFGQSuQsZZwZp5goveA@I5CxfkVHg1X@KrjerMXizw1dYFtz00u5aO39ZuymfXYxVAJGRQE5BQk3AXFc91g0rH7LmeOQuoKYUoIMvQ9QA5/iJOriljimfXkyvMBZqczfAa47Nju8ZxmBL95OSytHJ5/oIzQnR4ZveCJZStZCNHFpWSDVYjVmji2TMusXHwrlavA92e5YpqLp/Lq1qhkC@qIP6Wc4V8CchGLsh5VQXmkSuXysULaLWS9CpBv1lHds@i1lyhXy1I6RV2lmejRdKvHln2WUkTGPtJpasgLiVecYlbB@@q9frqcbgUqBLvqkK9puXLYNLQpGpUqFJVQdUETREUDf@vMaj4f/PwKvxVfEIsTeWO8KSjRyDFgwLjkAd4WEvgkiPXpbvM7pjGihC7A52eqrTrub7/TwhzR3eOmdddix2rG3vd1/Hbbv7QCgYrQjwdDS3Hx61q/1wQ9oYdyCByexbgDjw823WXBSiSp0/gcbD/9v2j@L281A/jg@oBOeykeohxtLeze58rkDuPH9298sqH4PLkwd69o9haZL5R1HwM4hf3Hjy4ag1fucdPD3pj18Obu/f4aW72iJ1wcx6Xg2sxUOxMgYQPtKKIh6oKWSP5YmRQONwXeDtXJrdDY74wM8pofI/tPLT8eOsg27xa4Y6i7Yg6wS6gYxL8FpbZpUO09NzGcGRDKZY5bkQc95QUZdJ1bVvHj8331sBxoPukY5qopts2UiImfep6dvfU6pprIBpDGmUFP@yNmeDuA5Dh2BhgAqAl4Wm/XfwMPC7F6Nhjk4xHZKUjvNAJjZ7VH4CkcepGAbiOrhO4P@8F8c35K7jZIWBpULdrPvb14FyC23mMAzCJEs/v8vx9PdCl4jOC8tOgwgd5vo8z3LYfdBtqFdS7ta1cCdj8rozj7hZRp7qkSFVAolI4r7vbykbb7NfyBWUL@@KanNlO3DdLpeo9uHje150sMMlsBQdSdr2aYz0jRtVRK6DeFzcIaZrndiZXU2RSqbDRTB8w2aHEVfnb7/7gJ3/@rcuvfnb5w99C@Y/cdT1DxzXsqIgTqlaH@rhIx4HUcilfKmtqKVsql3J5pZDP48JIpVgqluWsIislpVDKl5VsKVcGwS2Hyybz5WKozUvSBtmxcQAvyzR2aaMC4B0DP3W9SYeUxEGdS7A1PuRlSk@ThB7bx4Q3IQ5Pdpy@aQMMHAsM6FbYDasG3TaBUmpFApB1YpDEvXu7MqLoDlpwReOuzPNdtORLsly8w/Mm9dktoWzKuyxOCc9v5ANmkeU7UINjBgA/WcDzA7TsFXCChucttOzusKrooUXF@BDsmPkwix1ZihDMQYumMQAvYmgQbIelk6MZ3UMLJok@95jPLvjx/NtRdtDngAVjAO5HJd3Z4fl9ZtnZQZ9dWuw8y@gX0bJDL573wALNi@f7YOh70LB5vgNGbGQ8b4DJmOrghp8Xx9PunUDn@SlDDyKI5yc0tG4c83w7csdk3g1zk0fsVqhFYaXeppYy/nhejTKNwbTYovF8LrbkoGz377@rD4Ku2WfX1GNvA0p6/76mW5Px3r3O2293@v2ON93Ze/sAvXZ374NAMx17nX4njNhpw@VCrN37qn48nF69oNT77XZFt5d6fbHdzunOFa/2tG1iDiHWC8hZePUxoWF7F7x277e39WWLnijANvKXIbw7eN0ZwvuO3mFe0UW96HvS6fBVaAagxjRTHGpeuG4Jm@cx8GsnO9QNz62ifVIjMl1KP20U5FaVepAhqE5y9QL9eyl86jjenj6bNiY1uVWb1IoqG2XrpfjmRM1bfHZtuKWU85U1fUtRc5lJBZfUub0kSQrKFkkptzdektSj9JYKCtQa39zaEviG0toqFJ9tjKHi8bGlKqVKTlZJmlm1YgXiyEmZEHykG8XWVjFfmUUuFjO6pFaKRRD9AD8BCBAdHOBuk1Tq1NSP02nMOh0ghfLQgpMpLbRV7aUm2UmNZZJM09VJTamyI6KJfAVaKtXF7w6MDTyfhjCgfQA4AQ0KlySmeKVc4iEPkoTrNnHYjiHnLCeXLs7O/LOz5kXMKiUwzYao3/vS0fHR0fvArUAimbKRvXo4uPvEM5HnRavg376/K@4/jmz4SQHxHgrHrifuIo9b8GFScuR0BEqUeB@6dVCgIzeIE3iuLe7RZfMgYUce0bk@Ynjsr3h0fwHO4cA9ZSlDJL@KQpyO5yfgFxesLtFrdTDpXZKiuSJ6@pQKFO16vdauDc3hKJhCEaNYXyT0cwQzMPs@yzv9Akzf9AiNftbz3GHo0a7JF9VObZKYCALZAflu7GUBYrtGBOX50O0@VzNGtYufXLhTu4Ngqm14d6pmzfQ81@NBg@WrvS2nNnZ8vWc@MT08FGL/8ToIOnimSqpHzPQ6ae5h6F3Uqy6EukecWR4fjYcpXah30otOOCESOyCaUl@Kin@GEwKQc56/qPZqJPUMgr4Au7dOUl3xTnorVwWM3SHtNDjJz3vPe0QlhVyVqkEphAVNkGIKMaCna/UvgnzGQB9Drw25Cav8GKBiYgAYaoP66OmRdVE1ajZJCWSSpjjKVfu1BkY/x8emACKGIDTOWzif8R7qBi/G0HnWoblXpwm95o879CM8RO4oqlyoTsBNKeaqA6hv/dmk6tVGY8@s2mANZ0AILbFeBdwCCgHMy/PU5Vc/Sm8K@Rpzq1JQ5zhs3RbbtUnVweNTgVJqWg08Mo2cnM3jQtt8MQsihFrIKoWsls1lhSK6gvxA91OgGtZaW0vZKZ4QPitPZFHJKqaSTcnPre7zdPY4hXINRV46G7h7znhI0AWqDKmV2uGtpzPqBqCo6xJ9U6DEC0ymiuUC3A/IyMoOKKQDU7dZhLRAtI2UvZ7CQOtH49Feo1Wp7E1GXwKvlPBiq5ApypmX6XQ1tZau@eYLOlt0xwIC0QG5yJlo8UdrQNPhLBHxx8MG1DqYlKJaaTQ6WNainNVkDYpptc/7m3ydb2XltYICdXZBJwMUwjjL/LwISE7czG3URj3BNqEOlbJa5eg2kgS5443pRI1WUoWylN/Iy2xyhIHgRiGLRNySVDPacZNMJZNFNZmcKdXpZBUnotf42bwgVbXPKIdMAssmydtqvrDFgwDIV/iyykOwGcfFXBI5yvkG2dVNX/dwAonDoQqSA1X9jLs4u9iscxOR2xtatqVniWMZ@DU7yzgWuXuu182SjtUnPT3AtixyO1Da/YrIHYKeZ1JTYw@/aEBYfHocCkZrhQArdHYtGEwHJihDIjelk42BeN0VaongO0pqMQT5AneIp2lsqs/wV3z2cOcx/u5tJ3B3Ctn@AviVwb307OHTx08f36MnJsw2Mn@ea5sjEt2CMhHb1USVjvnjygxIBotW@RxLvbdx/p1Ia3gUAMmIglinx01ss1Sa4cFH0hohn3ePTGaz/oy9m7gVFEBz9Dj1BmnRVeKmhWo6eVcHgXKLJKHKdW/YUFWt1VCLIJZA19WQWVBVVaqQi3aC7muuA31PziDTm5k6HirxRTKd6hkhKvptUu9n1mV1mjhp84WyRs89aNcV@ZisJW9v4HfCBZI4OV6rqxuZ5JOKlkneTWq5xEmquV7PKNOkRDYy6rSHa9RwNZSUhHCquXFL20g@zVRK/WxFyeBThWclSYS1xHY7u50u@xylZJJYQPBaeae20z/YiVb37@zWS@o0PAwj8azNl4phFpvrgDI182x7IX4dZKFnOHN7pd5@nnX927gIPllNJs6SJJG8SF40ki0A3WjEZ6vUWrPs45K@cN2DliuQdIKkQ1uxnPBT8aKDLyS3E0mc2Se@/woImtYDbdbRsQdffK4Ck0k4buTgjgMc5QUxKp/HeeuE9Hzkf6CWtIf7j5273j2TSzTXztdcXJNAqjwDyZNXzjtfAv0VaitJmrXEpJYLJ36Vel1QNlU86qxIKiAA9JSCIJ/XGSerU4@CCj6XX/1ObrJZArsqK2BX1XxGrdeVDRBBE6PLT38YeFNytvfuzgOSxGnkn/z599XiT/78D@jS@eQFnVpWtWICQqJRKRQTZ2ejszMQAC@YXz7RSlxbBtgCNEmKXi5uiNUKkUql8obYlhIMnSAqF5V0whcS4YaKQl5IpRRJTW9oJTkNPufhcVIpVS6BNVriQZ34Qp5PJ/YOrLyqbG9uQcm2tJxaXWs0eCUeDSfxb9P0ywkuUXr4/JwQsBj1br9vqdQkSWEbeiWQzVfCJryhhl8Ja@R5rY5rGRU8xCVaLbCBB0Dg8p1kPSNtJAno2aTeuKhetDJ0yQEd9Xi24TSvIKO5hjuGF502HPiZGz79mSa1UgcfrJHN3PjQ51MbaUnqdmmfg8s9BKGeYCTbNkm@DvSyIUEuN6IVAuwnCM305Vd/W1ULP/nzXztvn7ffV1W1XC4XFDXxs59tjp2xb3brP4OIT6KD@4CIDKuLxHrkHpuOL8bjDbSjsxz8mpnlxOMUhB0oaYWxYoNo8Fxi7KAuxsJHoxY4PkFAHrX6jtmloxXcCUrTtFrb7Ki8booG2yCgjGSpLkfP5kpXOS7Sc5iu5vWNLIVBNvDw6UYrzZ1xb6EXbo0Ffa/KvTUDBQ5DkMZco@3bY29Ed1qnaDyllSW3IQqk8BYeQ7gGodMk7LMF4MLQT1@LyrLsU6xReZvgOel4qCGIItxbECU8LN@ekpHu@SYNaTkgJ4gYhOaTenRxM1UL0rZZhDZ1TdHSswBZwnLHIjmgwnFvgWxJsWCByEmsTQhQBZ7yFiAAypAKAVstskm0NDmzMpnq7MTECzwfx3EBhdGRfhxGQ2hdQFMcuYrhwAlUR/wiMNJFWMPA9@YcIyAMBlu/VwPlE6NTGwrzFpDD5I1BAazTAdYQLRq5fXuWq1rN6qYJLRHCP7ZGOFZL68FZnlcAFmnxt4ClgjiVyWBlv7VIdoDxDM0uUJ3ADqGszkUlPFovOA7@b0y0SJFXqop6VLEAYX2xVmEAyiAyop3VoUE2a0RRi2kSZ96AvBs0U/TAp3hoojm5JarvR54XkMOfJaKPewGzOpof/w7p9q5pnw/PY4T7BBSwMT3wNhjojBl0Tdsa4sJAHK1GprcfRLHjWFAUy6ahe5YHajBdJhidhJjSlDRGm50cSfNBtzOqOYJ7DfNpfNFYGJrAW8eT@cJ01qjoarhQof7IdehRfgGyJtzVCRQBPAoSeOQGJsv22DnFL@6FdUMjz@cISglaDlI@5pgeTeg6ps/i4mq7jmfqxxFussTsi8QYdolaJilKaA4uK3FicGkaiWa4A9oT4rhjm0PI0qFp0gMP/Iok9UHoG3dwTlx6aAFdDe5Z0P04vnSXIVg6tY4t6QhPVxfcHp6LQIEDFJATsfmx9XqgaI7tLrFd95jY1rHJpjVS88ci4kdMCllQfLKA2dkNiK2gyKtqWRwEU7IsFNxFeBWZsZSdi7uWmqavvzVlLdXGGj2nPZgFtWKbJ7ozh196nXPhQIo/9Tl6CmSNoOKQArsYs1xomexAtSSecZhMi4D7LkhYtH59iIIxRZwuG6X4BJ8W/ZFtBdTIjTzzhOBACId9DDBNox1mAVsxlPYt2gHQtgctC09mDLwK1FwGcuJ1UwY0vZDBO@QW0VQOA0LKGJRlAGBg1dcWoYMfRMVy@EEXKkakc0TIV6B1Drvghye/heSH8SPqRjM9J3NG3mQtBIedDk2rRliziCz5OQu2DqRnWvQ18CxADpfkZC3FZwBshk/zDHQc/2p0Ru0c5SUVch1SliCEENUAhYoKOrIcPHN67pN5uIjkjg7cGb@KgFQPRH96eirSQ0jHniWaPn5Gzncd3ZZGfQvEYVcKzOEo/NC2ZUijCO7MJLCvRIqjwWhrgkJtrXx7yt4c1/Nr4fLbVLLnJ7FzPMGvpPWHJ6hbQYZ7PiWoexb9kqKRCpcDM/pTW9mziP4qSXqiX/ICgRCCYCbZadbIArBsxzjO9k671dDjhDZIAA61aEaOeDSwF1mGfmSyRr04hBsgH429OvYxXU8AkHg2WzBLmpUwCjmNrKF9ZOG6fcc8JTuep09T1P//ae/r99NGkkX/jp6ig5MB2eLLsZ0MNp7FBifsOiYHcDK5mGFlEJgZQAzCNkzG53ce4r7HfZXzGvcp7q2PbqklhO0k83F2f3P2TCyk7urq6uruquqqahNLIwOnliT2iCVs@/QFHmGbEZ84T@1w0Vq2Q9UXfnXY1HyPIljIU7hz3QuUkxbj9wV/X8D3BX9fBI2qZluLNotk@OoOu4NcjwEIqiSCWaoyd5zgN/hCkEEOF3kGgSWXoXfoptwtUm1Fb/4F41hUjAE8MQWCO6ls64eL1kV74jm3m@2t7ACYPUGEgBEH0K020fS25z8j9Uc3o6nrhV7B9kHijcQbX3WvJDcwr2Af/QEixmB6DTEp62AsPZ1YIJAdBggoh8FHFA1K89TQ3PezZNNHYJxWIqAxI9aSyLRJ@pKf5DsQl5j0TFgdUFsDhO/9LgGa8EWomcOXhqrV4cPMhTKqbJruOYQlcimS7SRQMjJVeK3Zp0HSsEqnFZpAdhRXi9GuqO8wFK3IJ62bd3L8dfSffjb6fZgX8dgTw/KGsW/oUwWDDUCEkNOFqCoOi9q4AgbZTXvkzGDnqrB8KndraGYzq9QMbge74N0O592rlDb4XZPHh7JaJCaJgs8Ky2IRurgs8rTkeaFIygT3q3my2lIxgqzPCwjAyMVWc2S1hV5tUSzywiEWa6rdakguCMkFV@HSizVItmU10J6qanvB4WmDdIpREAmAl@dtFMSgaUJ49o2DHhw/Xo@nqFWpNoM1h7hA8hCK2Mhn3XZs6y0NaW3RigBARlwB0OP7xAtGdMHLp/1f/hrFpFRrFP@SbMBrBTAYLcH7ButAPpORDgwCf2KL9gGYu4mtlpHI0zEB/i/H/yUs9VL9l199mQuXzIdf5qzI/36Xl22krDZBNekjn9vBBdkILBW6yeKtC9pgYIfQHCa0V3hQFH4HC8CEirEGN0YoKVLc7jUvkH2BpzizB34kKSpYOWGJkvoYLzRW4tyj5N7UiKDEbregZ1xMEua@dr@AsjIEG6MQJ9XTitikgJc@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@6QMKghP2wy77YZqXdEdgjLAW79kBHAkcczTE4/f1rADKGvBLB4K5SX9A4hrcvC1Rc8cQfduqCYfzH9bD70/FrsZ3LvcznXuQ1kuGVu4hgLvNiJ9iugEjqwza6@Ozmdwzj2J0u2WUPNnOEtZNGgJY4ReX4Pehlzo0zmThGaTRi3z4Pb65wZjdOL2MYdadHbqOX10QRVOOukVyg1brXsy5fd3A5nNizJfIF3sVCFyTA5Me/6JM4BlWnL@8YtAy0goBCNh7O2Vbi3gzxWhHf8tN3RyP3FgnWRaML0wMrjR3Y44xNU4RRQmIpXEjfH197c5zSaDVGgPYl3ojb9ckwgc2vCyNDJgxjBKDIcKc1NulFMIH2uiMbVa1MHALQkEYBhQB0rXfdde7FwSAkPhMHITumQjVsNTJZd2a4NFfGNqq2INcFBKZRoWoa7jDAzTfVhmjUTpofSvWKgOd39dr7arlSFkcfRfNNRRzX3n0kh1zxpnZartQbAiNaj2tnzXr16LxZgxeJUgNqJuiDUTr7KCrfv6tXGg1Rq4vq23enVYAG4Ouls2a10rBE9ez49LxcPXttCYAgzmpNcVp9W21CsWbNolZVNSOoJ2on4m2lfvwGfpaOqqfV5kdq8aTaPMPGTqC1knhXqjerx@enpbp4d15/V2tUBHbMKFcbx6el6ttKOQPtQ5ui8r5y1hSNN6XT00hHax/OKnVEPtTLowpgWTqC7RFbon6Wq/XKcRM7FDwdA/EAwVNLNN5Vjqv4UPm@At0p1T9aEmij8h/nUAg@inLpbek1dM5IPUAVGJfj83oFT6KQEo3zo0az2jxvVsTrWq1MtG5U6u@rx5XGvjBOaw0i2HmjYkEbzRI1DTCAWvAdno/OG1WiW/WsWanXz981q7UzEwb5QwVvfTkuQdUyEbh2xr0FItXqHxEq0oEGwBIf3lTgfR1pStQqIRUaQLXjpl4MGgQiNvVuirPK69Pq68rZcQU/1xDMh2qjYsKAVRtYAGBiux9K0Og59RrHCfDiR2BWQ3GuRcMpqieiVH5fRcxlaeCARlVyC5Ht@I2keQadazUBbYi3Ojr2WBfa@quvbhx0CFuV9uLlP//86bhWroiEOjdMBB/OYdd5FTmY0r/BTuN/hJ@hA4Cec3k96OCVOyix@9VYqBp7AwszOpgYSX5h3HNOLWU3qrCx0em8L3VK9deNTse0HlMzhMZDNSi1Kghr95QyZR8x1gxtaChUFgpM94MQoQ6/QXGw78wswU7IVJKp/w1trhN7DLpiNttzZDU0hSBgJZbCHjxzxwKA9XBpJCssxr4HTZLUQ7@Hkh2oYkqBz3Q78Bp7zoVcD/6Z/Br84M1BewGrM4vS2ezAmTMaoKCqZrgRMjDRP9K@A9oXSfKe4/w0SOX05pxJz8zg/VToHSnrUNm5MxoNUuYD1S@dQaR6OlqfkEWjpkqY7HFgAWsXyJh8DiZJJuS4ZGbUsxT@05nTH1NhwxY0NJRQU2SClwpR6huu3sq1kaxsKASJmgcZZb63pe@rH1DJzW3v7Efev/Hf89xCh0H0LYUNr0X12vTnTZsLwAQjyyaQZCjtjdmsVgfEMhIo/cK3UPAKC/H9WrhXXzm0rwNJQJC9tkd6m7gbz4YLHXtYh1/XS2@Pzk9OYOlEbHde7b7c2zf8Q8zvLf77Edsh7046w53CPg5yGn3SZskxCD40UzRX/ID9iYGzWSyIgRxq0OglWs38S6xYSOAcGCRLHWB3PUwEMUEzSMKZ0MVbZM58aih@jZ2ZkgFSoa6a2JuxvSAR3wZZiXhAHpqOljRqC/wHYfvTX01xv0OSgSSLkb8rcK7xhNe9BFaik7a@ez3hYxAskkkoPuZDcZ8GeCuXyBfkMSL9krytjSIItjjQOF9p2KkmIPE0ioWQeih5dkMT78hqK5VLOouFN99LfoPHj9JdgJwHbG9emjeAjCd@TdSBA0VXdrolIbcxsA6PqFVLBwItCKZEiuaeVFV9M6s2GwgVjHlF61QY8L5vlY02iYpw8m9J0LeZU9EUinD2JcfK38C5cd2RUPaVNVb@VjY@wbB8kzFT7dZvw1BFPvpWQUXOEJm@ih4E/0@kSQz8A9A4AXpALc2l4lGUJKhMK1BfiSjDW2XE0CwnATX1Vx8DMHf6wFz5HZOWoQW5EiAJ5Ogs1YuP5ETST8UQAJncRM8Cbf72XIfuNIedGVSnvyVMWR1tMJPueJoScq9QW8UK3PRe2yKxy1J2G/xhCpMMs0Jr8BSqir@x4nZJsx5UpogqL557CQZnKmtqdhPPM4IJT1yKFMmryR5wVk7OMrUOyIMrbcPp@edPIJberbUIbgrN4Si09kurmiIUgD5EfFb7SRGGruiOXM@J@K/wHRBN8ilAz31LXp0oHQDQ0wBdnBDO856QtxI681vcIEYMnRwfAmgi9Zx8L7ARPpYIBAe13JoZIC1tq7c@9gvC/lbD/nzC8SX0syBUiQz7mEgMJ3itJPAMXf8t3tpLQHn0uG4zi2U3G64lbh2K4mGzhKyPAZdd152B6GhjvwFHa7g0M@KDNDo4E@96Jr1BYD8bzqRFQgn90AyKTay90zbDcRuEmjcEuWGONhfkD@rS2LEn0kFkuEjviRQwr@LRQ2RhcmtZbOVF6iD4cgA0IScvIuKB2MMEa1SKCSodsByi4NDzlQuYJS63cyBywfS7dWc/4d6PItCk5/R8Py8NJLxQg1SdkMdMd85dn7oeWTRgKNAC4lMiz4a0S7v70y1K3rBHv5TsBAI6vkoEvkboCUY9@fx2fCaVULGhgHFl68B8e2kYTKTStnS08l2v8tu7hEqcwnW3Vhkj36uwSVwkLib@klKQd78@V6IjPvG66T99xCe@@88pPvdw9sAbtJ9LERQRRpkVbbar6xzhh@cVH4bOrKfbREGS6dlTNL@R6uNOiBeV6VA6UXTtuecsQQPoZoeLLMHopP7uXk06x@7IHgzdoQ16GoZWLHjFw8clPeKADWburUexxJw0SSvUWwbPZA2Xh9r4W3rs4M/goNObO9OUfgQyny1LmGcBtRg6xsezVn@/Iv6eRk@c/To7u0Elvw7hkZlee1egm@6vrfsiH1eZTwsQgFzgDiOnM3RM7qDPY1G15E5T2nGHKnB5XwENx0uRFrb2@W4txt8CieiAN4SxQmblyEPvBGpmazFu9RZWjzw6Zu4c1q2ygzGrXopeWzam9IRV5Ds8hSiI/KucVpXyZfYW6NWBD8v15N5@@SdjDwh8Bfr5F3HcEscItMT15WyANZmUCemzBbiQO/OQ1mhaiWEVGw5gFxqFgHYWUajhz8t11KBTRRCKpNPCClfijEyB4oMpL1IdWHI6S7ohPSmSJjkKoAhSogtz1jGsozOr7l@jt4NH3Bxil8GF6VhCTmlIryNVF6iEyQBDMKfXOsrsofrwjNnefuyoRQhYlAQM4aDlyUwllOSCnth8G/WcjrXcGSzGiQj15Klk0pu70@Qjqbd27Yg9546jdddcR6RPEWYrwma52SPSFpf4uNw3ovhEmCZMMTrFBh5C9ZWefTaPEnFR7OB8K3aWD9BhHc2CM1l/U/HHu8dzHzfFGwwrVRuNP6UId3T52vfftzrQ8c76FUTCZPWqQytGB5eMzpIfNVARMvlUejyFiPsk7hF69IBy2G4PaKePz1qiRg/glQOZ@hRyGUJ6ohu8PXZwXZr2M9CRlKnOp/xFyhc4F9aSjvLy6Ut02cQPDBClYicd2KHYghsMVoSPKNain@qgW2AeVyJ4OmSfXeX5JBH1CUYxDtK4w@69rc4ynW/vM6SFDwm0Cr6m/R5I8hUWa3UWBGWFFDDFY0jh92hlbbp6fK@@ti9QDiBwbfrsXeMRPEhT2BlTbAE28I/@qbNAGThoStYMzajwROjQ0gBzAbSUwchhdRWlv@GMOR6vjJPTCBQIfk33@mzJGugcvZfzqY1VFr0lFjEluXm2mZgnjaoEDMW/kfxyKrKoS4orAHAYY6hfzAMEdBIj7PFQYOT05yHOCyEqxwgqFvM4LeEl@ZgFPiQx35GossDOrlYiF1fiWx1GOhYICBbxZQJEQGaJLxJAgY0uFhetxMv4/gQlQCBWvM8Uh6GQoxKmoT9yTEDKoZczgxWllRdWTnIwfdzZNUMfff6mr9/mtK@56Fegj49hK52Pfn2VC30NNbu9Ha4aqgn0MPVWQx@BFKaOsL8qfN3/GeQSqDmQKwn3QFMyQlKG9P3CHIegZYLelvnREwdo4jhUMoaCR4dx6Typikr96nDAWsjF/X53dpGkIwP0hP/q3qqYDYWJjLxIXkzI0Z6Nu6wQksSawK0eu4WaLnlToOGEPE5Av1U6rdsX75snJ7oSLC6XytFo7Mx2c7kcMvGlHkqg/LbQlDR0s@HS2f71aJSd3v599v4yS2s/ZsseeW5BadAODAlMCi/jzgYcZ4M4QFEsnQYCj90bB3X9635fD2jBE0ocPBg2Lsm@Yj1BG9DQd3p53@Tg@pNgg/0ndhD790/hz75bmwVNCUUdQ0FtoN7FTUKdngF58EUffb/8kyoChguz8maCfcssHn7CHQTjxGiwyBnURLOQZP/EG2c0ci3xAbORPU2QRSVS4eREr5DjInjCiERBF6MRcJglnJvhKDif8rCIzusITm1MKmpHedljpEHdGVQW01Si9UMCthXo8hZ2cwu9fS2RGCRM6Xr/CLDMh4D2o0qP7WmqS3SKFoatXs7g4AkwepG3YnWfUBGTbGKSZg@XRqLGo5v50R1OUtB1k2QBFRlAw0s9WVPcJ27iYpHvIw1zDEPiRHcEPqrG3f7XLY1ftyzezPv9x62KFFTBA/tZKyLHlX3dgkhnADQD5fQDemJ05T/SMK1PIoFQLOBg6NPquoMVOljBMJ53iz/fpkqlkng23doSpdIRPGCSn6OSKOOLoyNRxgwq@Pub4vbu7j6vuWXzE7w8Ui/vxBHA4LuIu1ezMvyEb0UMcIPtnrTIZ9niM2v/Wad4cLjvZVulo3Y2O4AnvlsqW5I/8NKp7BH9aP3gF8pkMtln3U/Pvrnbx9@tcjv57LL1bNpODvaRy4AMpeu5W52n7cB9NDO7NDZ4F9Dekh@p0rM9zOIqqwqVHmFsz36C1aUgNrpedkO@9TgOl9bYja6jvXcmmAQFVHgVwhFV5Q0MkR/bSzTHw@h0HXTAg/2GUriSHyjX57MVZbifuFoB/1RlgxCQMuuNA6DxhGMJneSGMX4AL1t2JmgBvyGZl7tnGDb8Hc47kn@zP8g7HzYvUmIzJzYtsZlI0B@8/2HzwnyWHeK9IlzMvxkiOFpAN0PhDUnQI/2BIhcj5DaMZxQAiZBUODQVnlyPL9H4rLQ/DJ@U4evewHhCV4@yiYQOmbDKxqdnkzsYlk9Q4i5hPKFwxjzm/WBBoSO1GGpMO1HxxxdFINtjR4Cg5TETpOBCk3jSB5X5zC@r3sixNig2kwAjWeuvT2je4wvYi55RTGc@okth0CgFP/Jb3Bv3OXiX0MYv3H6AAB2osDqZo7CR5EYSzzroagG/l9RNQTGeev8k87Gvw9KZY8Wg@f8UGhPQpyc64Z5N6B2dY9JHpn9i6B@vaE0luCxF2/PJjKFVGV@P5sPpSJ55EYlw5PzW7ngm4YgSIIbDEdSF1RlGhgLMfHDrUBiyPiwcerwUPRe7zjNBplrF6WBm@ORII0L2hxTM7V8jc9vMDhETxQ7MA4SU78rXt4cjD0k@VzlbB/bsEnMtUH5mMZzzuRnZ8zCnTgRjt@8jnSHI5HIezGfoysZ0Zg/GtiU2ztzmzF5WYdsCyWfezZjQw0lyTkjg5JNNx3VPIcw9kkNCFPG7Qp5DGL09Wspgcx5bHA0aDBpSNRVkggacBCF2Iko6v4bGKkLHgKs/YxB0lFcWb/80Ui6xtPKip5GEFHQB/qFptjJ1DNWCPnf8iZMwGFV/ZipekJWucaMd08EvrOSY0Fu1TTUdeT4oYLnE9nF3GjgTO7Q5TUeGwYlJnmX3Be@LOJ8psQd7I8n7ivIv80H@AMQK5MgfwhcG897k9llmM56kUk8uPBkcv6HvIyg8Z3xf/KyNrCrPyikcfEwJ@c4nQ14sIzvUkGkPTJgRVfL8Bwj9kT0A/Ja39hJZ8WIj9d3TrNn64WLS3kxdTH69@MUkTOSSrHbZtNiQh9lqxZJzBXbGrBX6qbzSPCAB5k4UF5NwgYsJuXXx6b0kASCSTbV@yLZ/zQJCFxumuZm92GCChIYMMcne314WwWdX0NwIY5HdMJ6Ym6Ya/NR3eVPA3kp/cQz5hcl/AQulVJKZHvScWR9AUQwQ3U2Ail321XZuZzu/A5rQwFmkZ8417rdp7/rSWYAo4aE6C1vPxS8hbggR4m7h2fvwcgH9HA4mmAaaRtSTCS3kEiqnObVj@GwFdTLME1AeqJxCEmCIi@mXsfHwERV@SwDLqbKU0YJdBzXuS@H@6bljbMf2cF2LRocwR6KXAfuIkAk1jZAl463lUFNNlyQFm2XE8ZUDg4xAYHizG9puMXEnaSmsmZnkPgrRGDUzwry@0Tm6MkVDM/SZFKaST0X@8LuX//2/az9vzDcOt7MfZvB3vvHzxt6rDX6EB/j1Qv262TjcOMBie3cbyyzowPD48r//D9Q//DvAwS/LA/jncFfB2ltuHKaLVOXXjcM9eMhvb0O7//e//gv68Iw1Nsxs86xjCUJsX1Hk2J4Q78J3UcVeslqaDJaVPC4sCIM9DEE3hx/oGLXYfpUjM92G9Kq4QfefYX/u@6PILZ4cs@bkKsSWDOVPAZIRVyhiA2kGqVwo@kLz3VBuG8i8AZrin88zex5oAP@U7hx@k77rxnMPXYaesVoEA5jiFkGf54fD3HcJ372jkFA@JftKhETVTq61r17sAzu8c535sBv2klDTddy1b53LDPJhxuldg0418Ubuj7PsDbDkOL/9KttH436W/LizU4KUni4zv4AgKLORgGJITqeWmMEIuGP4C8@YowQE@hP/TEpl5wApe@p02YYVzvAERRrNcqVet/h4GLuTCUTpFP0LAjzmIZFpNbTI84sJ1KzVCyKx5RfkcqTzmojNO3KOlUlH0uwNS9lrQYChPqB1UPUnU5oNKAiJas0AAhfJ2L1ex5bfUsaThAo8t4wnV85oWkyQbxj0Bm9VAwld0p/FzLVQ0kO0IKTTtNAhrLEzt0FFLyboDerjQQtzvJ2Az1pJN6bVxSdrX5aVWn2veIJnWvc0fctN38KIopQQtOPzTJALZyL0Yry2FNFUOXM6eKQW2zC05qkUWLMM/UEMPB6Wah/DEmR3KAISqBZ0R3qV6cNmkS4MPHLrcMwemxY5D5ixEQQ/WqoEcFb1LIOyE7ab4cZggThzJ04BPZT59juMgCiqpC3DCQlAK59V7LAEQ32oTR1GUxEKO2LJbWkC@yEJHBhLKYAEQ8fjTS3wwTZ49/BBSzhaQp8EGl4SJrJUv0DKFhVUw1GgpFrcOGpmbKdqdYWfrKcvcwHRvW74IpHLb7/Y2d17@epbjBl/InsbDwYrZVALmF7ZAIMk6hQo2fi@WEwkE/wKE3qtNonQ48DiARy6dd2ahBU/PsW7BBhYLkGwbikxFVeX5koCGUCcORncEUBHSc0SqdR3hRZ2rH3RM3@F/xKWqs0Mh6ZmezT8xWbSa@PwjgMiKM3R2Bm7Mzwex4XZpswumFMfthD@opd13H7dwTur0NeV2R4aOnVdDEqYudeDK507MmztF02YMEDw@WxZIA3qtcORoqRTa1ihLCoNDlUt@qKo4LVWe4BOubgloMzHwGGawWRAL39bepri7EjCJoR5HjBiFY8QNddRnZ2JOyeuqJyVo4jJTGhDz4eb0T1bQbiD/RDAV2onmPlI624TqAtTYiB7rdYkiw36pPvKBS6H5YArkOkxVrqLab00qqi1muSGeeo@suSJF4d@QrugKowj4hUDM597mJQqrlX1AgmiFkJpTfIXMcs/z9FJFuCkDzLOU@TlREHzEX079DzK5S0bS5jSo5QKwUB6fCoRBxDtNrkEdyRXwBGlxwqlseLR5steyWUS70flAfY1VSe25LAvTQUUNc6ZRXxaYP@rZ8eWKFfgn5MPZQsF5aPSP7DffsKs9fjmJb75gqieqCEggkozHPncos/UzxiiBMySszh9SYAgLr5k2MB6JHkjBSvVE0l7ntSt0NxuB1yB7GpLIVxZR@UkwawpZAN5IpV3Mp3JXItSoS@w8Wp1pdmShdW0YBPX/RNbo8mToFUfEpPyESC2oyDSCkTA7U8ChmcPdJK8bam7KMaunsTzdIhlWaECsf0kC2QP8@xaytzHFtuSLbYLOI738QXx7b28wfeWhZnjAd54@mW8kX48c6T/LZij8udwxwvJHS8KuPYwd0y6M4dWJIropKR2bgzHXC5pD@70hoMh2of62k/sRM7SANCCR9eR2RQPks9h39YsJyIV/2Eruh@hk9D27p7xhZ3fkZ3fKeCaS49l539q59O/ced3Zed3C7jXxIy8FO1k@Otv1@NAJEyFX8QOL4q7XMz80p7uyZ7uFXA3jRnmP7yn6d@ppy9lT18WMGMCHzhwCtf7uZklkVLjuFoN3C0yKgNxCrMCxnOliboXXoltif7o2rsqorQuvhj/VxL/V7ga0VMdyWprMcq@Ls/qKQfLs2TJl@ZhkBX3hPsrQ730/soNK9BH5AbFizQZtmZSUQGB3OKPwWlTJpAfg9XX33weizOv7ZRbiTPDago0a4R5M5jiLPlSYZWA9Qkz8hwtacfN@unW/2IyjO2fZBQaII9De4t3DMmdRFfBcKz4teyM1h2E3ZA6R4hVJDkJ2bmM9vbZ5cn6VY0SW0T2xXglgY/aOF0yZqByNA8gMhkBbTKyvtKq0DVXqRf8BvrOheK7LHv8RVz6reTSbwuiLhWDdaSypcFP8mKgp23v7t63B3CtDP7BCZizoPw9s@r/BYcLq@4fpT5Sp/PW8bwNLVmUoefp5jICy4hwmdI1lJkV8LqYySX6H7z3k09tG1q2ZVBWPMM4fltuoO3Cvuz2nP7gavjjT@OJO/155s2vb24Xy1/yCcNQyflTJmctVN430kyxmq85MUtEkjantazNAQg0zCfZahI2hCTz@aTZKhS226bA@TnmfEx8PhAAIBF14o3wjiRys/Czh9NQsgdDNLbXo6N/b44x50Cy1MgeX/ZssSgI9L9O5y2B3mDybRcICSQiO0yqC6vn1DRNuhNGXjmR1CEXkpb@U@/qbDCusn1OJBISJfhZpQMBNLb4RX0LTYtMLm2xCczHX4a9sKWEbTJ@TZlaD9UCyafbO22zAGT6QF@Q4a/s0ZxPBFO/mL4njDP3Iwlw6zzmRQ53kZwZClzQkD6gDdDvmCmZIzjl4v5q62rou9aOD6MVgG@HCodopf3Ygqnvh@4AMJgK7pHrjk5xfFULlqSGJV4FnQkyIWJY8xt71PdHQWUrHrJTZYh3wn2kHLJI7dDARAghidH3V7ogmPoKm3Wlpdivj4cNgPEluSusgNLxxUorBVa4hNbQUE4f2jSi9Xh4vTmnE4/pRMCcLR8JyhEd8Jv2fkN8X6vD6N/YsyEattjaloc2Mk4G5ueAHP7ncjLFJiqSk2t7F@aVD5lmmLmCXHyf1qGcWn0Jeq98iQ3QuoMdwItzVRdwNxtQdsOHkX4EyvdM5xCHMlhk7xPYjnz2Vkyd35NCXTKJSEv5MW7ahbkbWXuGPsapV5HBVnTA6bWH5FIv2iyvBJ9f4ThjzjHYA2Y2u5NtiPP5EBbxZeDTTMINOYzpUhYlIWJgnJs/OoG7V5a4lD9kfh2JqbZ4IG0oT/@VGSQaX9M5BazF7hhb4iWeuRND@BBBgMMZkDfjVkRszP@ZFdvm@u5CKeyntypYRrocGtT47rrXOgK5B/sZlFdPsIfo6/gKIYbtMAusQlBLrXQdxr1BflrlbDyS6nQw90@nQ6lWOh2UHzqdJLfCwoQmBGn3XpQue9ez9My@Gtv25O/Zruel8dLt6dwwukDWgwORrJyVkxhq5X/KTJcwDunNtJB5@gWJHPjGSCTCUabHjYZoHNer75qCvhk0Jl13NHKkeCBlpNqsh/eDlofduRKbWMpTv8Y2phUy6EJKcex5DcKFe4iD2@mg@3@nk/KcUV8bnY3gCf5703x7KpqUcLBZaVA@xEZMUYSRwQBIUk8R8YOn5dpx8@O7ClBxPDo0DtQfKHRI9Q7mw/nIOTzI8l9@582XKAospw5ogfJdll5C3SxXPrh0e0v40xveCPpUTKij/8LMAXFreOPsQ2WdtoRg33XnAYJZqI9AJbQsI6gq6JVBkKuVa6Ig7B4e2YAgqJQHnFQeBoYM@0uRfJHMDD3S61NmuGV584mURpP8M4MtJi2RvN1Kxmz94YFovCkBLV@f1o5Kp5jx612ljmks143F5aADTIMSLF3LkAx/5fA0dxISKujLXEqs0Y/hUt@TaBx@9zH8bk036pXXVcznuB5zJmlRfMoV8nfhTzfoUxX7hS6hoG93qxisQeXktPT6XixQqVvZ9@grWphjv65pqnb2uoYpKDF15roW3ckANI1BB1uOIa/6jE138KIO71H0Vi0f1cr30Hww4s5EG8XGcHo8qqnj2vnZ@sVBugjnw1A2DB/R8@a786YRrukvVjBhaJ2yxEJbqrSpJX1SFuY6@EelRkVUTinjqfaJfF1GzlhBt8TS4kUFVFBaOx0PRBdLJSpEMaYQjWuma1VjlyP7EvTn67mzj3GghU9308X@3J3KB5xqmOO3wLGuqU93PWdg7l8Yn@4S3HYxAQydOPx0x4vVxSTJV9HMUxJRfTKv4O0jbRoRYpQr9er7SlnRo6F9DpUEolWP1VefXt3hrItxcxrFKP@MJbPPxIxQamUTpi9EeYaQJBBMGQbDz@h3NZihV22aJjm83b90cfODXbg3vPYKu7nn@z5dJCIrzTFIS18cI0nXY@QE1WH0LvsTu/ubdY76grDr93YIxFrQSi9HmLgC/hv97h28MOSIXrrzuTtOU1prNbxcK/QdJ1Posw8AJtf62vgxpmq0J19C7hWSPYq31DSj1M4n1WPe5Bsg9Zfq9dqHRmQ1XOFLezZzb8@nvw9ripwaN3iSFKRVTCDdBKxrw564MGgVowvs5v685FpasZhCPJSy1IXB5XRmR12CMDGz23QRYfDrqyYzEa3s3k7@JcmGu8fvSrMwnepY6Y8jVNC7e@gU4py1hNJo/odz1ym0/S9JNJ0FfyeqrV/zKGX7vWteIMA0K983o0ILkp/updYpjy@@jOCr26/etUAgpBbWsIfE10c7Xn27Z4XvD0ejdYKvr@ItVuVlKVGuqampf4t18nK90qidvq@IcvV1tSnel07PKxGxeYZnQzcOH2TLpmbOAC@EAPrRCZXWcFJTILoYWkFxcHyORcFueBqONqO@b9C0RN/hcJDhPOlxWUO3qPr5fibuxIltSTUR6OWFuBRPUdBQLflrEq1X9CVc5xZvBy1KuPJA6NekGTW9QzHp1pNEwwwHS5C3LV63ivdYrhqER9KGxqMUom9AWQScb5uri9DVY2tvx9WWpIgcFYJEc2VGzPPhznmg2K12bnu1c0Cwr@qeRBDtWhloNAXw7ses63p/OGLQ5sOIgVb4R1MNo1pClDMjuvzqCQW5IKzjEtlwi2ZB@DRMBr39w1lSJNVaGGdq0q6sKLCsPbiePGaK6ueowUHq4ikq8dbKBDYfmsLH7mh1yPJr@5ecDS5Bp7fo/01/F4k9i7fuu@Qi/vjeWnOqfx8g857hjl0KI5tC9axceVc5wytpxD8qHz/U6mU0CTeiW4O8@D0yhL4nNplQPd3mrBtYVQUuRtko5q66JwrkmCsxcrswK3AkyFhGO/EiOGpk8Bz8Ag/y5uXQSbE6iKdlgswZyTA1VmAwm4jVdZ6OmblDCG5nlR8ok@Z9k5er4/UUK3WXj6ybj6mL@ekf2/b2mvqPbf9FXH2yzLKxSNqrECP@s1wjRPvrpT5EaIBZN0D3T/KV4TN/3wEU/34jSNavrxw/ZXT6owbx1V@D6P/f5eyRlXfiKo8eWXk3pvL8sS3vxVV@bMsv1zKub@pc5V5LRC12n8HO0u7214r0J61Iyu5536IUP2ho9/tr2P7MYSPL6@cPHBki/xq5P3Pk2Bb8@UOH1tC/Ru7PHDmyR3@dBIeGyMggkoE0ih@q7lHswu2wewXaNQlA@ON9IiRaNCMoBNZMJ/UIMpmPbQzVyS9TCL9U1/tSRmOnHbR6S7O1UB7rkrEK7XW9DntvvC@dire1cvUkzoNjhUCe84dN6W1S9H2yBZZc/EjeN3FGs1mHTcuPpqqIBYJOgv6YY3h/7CRDv6SWKt4m27BsP8bVmv1l/XrmI3yfpefu7czF@HMPb1hSId5je65xoG9HKZXxUuXT2nkdBrbe@IyJ3nN/n4F1p2vpyCbOL@H@G3bQV2tglJP8xZUndbRnshRiBp@3kvEO2pqpk2Jp@iPXDlCjt5jknl@vmH7DbaS/po3049rY/Jo2Nh/XRvZr2shm4xpZsyyVK0fnr0VWNN7UPsSXoS/eFV4Qhbc7dWeOM1m3hIXXMKjz@/B6rOX8T7MCRnYIfzT82RGp9KD9Xi5HP4F04t9joS9C2uDw8PHoDCcqhfKjhocuQPsDx@dz9ou4MWKq8DHFb0rPNbb4s9pZmgzwIUM832Hve7bqJnnPwySB0irvudezrn6eQqlpcYz4S5CZNrUSOXXvDoa3KYUdaDnEB@O8VL4HCn0VKpMo3w0Sz7fsmLoFAx7bSOCH@zWN@F6uK@2EFiYlnhB3XkziN5P4vsculoG3c2vFAbjdSiJGybZiSCJELJgNHVA6ncYqn5LMqMnCpzuQCQkUPN6txyPGAzgW11iv55WS632ZV/k@aN5cS9CVcY6FFwk58YGvuk6ba@LH/IkgczSH2EOeI9HlEfpFEoV7j9wWoVTO4doiaemRPGvJycdpgaxpiQUsQfhv3IL/aJfx2InwuAGOdwzXrimjy4SNtfOIlvuROlzdiJlLsTDC1eIkNjz5BYLHU3vN5qjx9UowInGE1AL4jH3lOPE@zqeqcWz9wKl/ZH3oK8UimNh4eu5P7WTybs3awHOM6vuXJyBVLCC6GRenqON2uA41QoK0HU/SBfTM9SWxkBavlDLXTt8pZZ0LoK@fW3InniJVztyJ8wUk5L8PEjGGA8MT2Pc3sVdsJJpSxkfbJFakSaygACL/jJuyExKqX8vTYXZdhw7riCVRr5TKotGsi5Pzs2NRPWs08UXthD6cVs8qMac6y/hh0bc/RfCWonY7SP346JU3DIg3xH@lVZi0eUVwOfbS042Y3R/7B7j8gTlGtA9Fa8VRFsXLeMKqESo8TIP4ii2A3Q4U8WH7XkBDzonxb8AF8dS4ny8e1AY0jWDiCu8ak3rhZuIsQAfxkuZj16hWYYeXJdyrf6OdUhMQYnfK9WJHzGIUJy2vseepKzE@Y@CYhHQffIxsIdVMdUuGsXbeUYH8Grtf4OYkF4Soh1NoeCL6W@kIVt3ScbNSFm8rzTe1csP/FHHmxTjdaJTuauibFoJrRoLzk5fO4HoSjTGl0LdJ75GQOXY2Nqw1Q7ma4kNeM92RCzRawYhuf0@ujdY7Lp2elo5OK5I00YC9hdOVeizm/O1M7flVtAesxqqIW78Y7PazZCT7y6tkFD0dQqRbNBiRdyHdWtaLFEFCm8ZDkeccLw5I@/HasqkgMY5WLsN0CFLbmAZmFjUM5AKR7op0Xg9If6pFHdN1OjJtOr@2MD3SxLmlqWb7SWmN/wmB3I8Mr8zJ6MpcXHBljmIr2amfQqL3gxjLxOFOblfGgz8UF84klqmOwkH@YuqOloORC8/wABTP9pyb7OR6NDJwy@8N@/3wIOjPh99s442YTvfKFYDN/wc)

[How to build.](https://tio.run/##ZY/LasMwEEX3/ooBQ7yShrRd5R/6gG5DGz3GtmpbMtIYNf15V9ihtHR1z53LvLRK/brWkNRE0IYIR3kPytuid1XuiKFnntMJMecs5yv3wcsQO2x5xt1iiuaG4igfJKsou6@qCIjPFv4nxsLLT7FKZEE4aBKeddk3Ok9nje83xK6BZ/1BhhO2bqSwsTS/2t5MvM6M9S4NPAa7jJTwlXiZpfMANTwFphNcpEQTfOu6JRIIYV1SeiSxdRafXblq4d1fAGyg5BuGHOJQTYN1EfTiRguHA5QnNq7@zCzBpAZa128)

This answer adds 3 Python versions: 1.4.0, 1.3.0 and 1.2.0.

`dir("")`/`dir({})` fail in Python 1.4.0 with `TypeError: dir() argument must have __dict__ attribute`, so using `dir(__builtins__)` instead:

```
                #       len(dir(__builtins__))     %13
Python 1.2.0    448               65               0  
Python 1.3.0    447               67               2  
Python 1.4.0    446               71               6  
Python 1.5.0    444               79               1  
Python 1.6.1    68                89               11 
Python 2.0.0    439               95               4  
Python 2.1.0    440               101              10 
Python 2.2.0    441               113              9
```

```py
print ([9,5,8,0,0,0,7,0,0,2,1,-371])[len(dir (__builtins__))%13]+439
```

Additional `()` around `[9,..]` are for Perl, space after `dir` is for fish (shell).

Answer (score 0):

## 374. Befunge-98 ([!Befunge](https://www.phlamethrower.co.uk/riscos/befunge.php)), 16334 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4DvehfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k] PPX~_~)"xvyq"\(2#CO|"14"   #:9 {?63#k9 #  a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--     mxf                  5  xAegguEa>2.8.7.@_;yiuFtMZWWWWWWWWWUUUUUzR           z      ]++(--[                   :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184  O@  R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]`L ;     >"082",,,@_     x-----x        ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####         ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(* [>]R 10G|'53'S   1111  \) >>>>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#  # #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###>>>>>>>>>9 [@,,,"279"]>252O @_xxxxxxx h$s o# 326 ########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>>>
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ; >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########  ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#e                                    @,,,"361";@,,,"362_ ";># 23-2g_"01",,@_      # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11               r3o5o8ox xxxxx .-#351$#&  #
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._>]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-'4o'6o@]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnMM>nMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#cs 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!-- e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;#?>\␍try:len[id];print(349 )#\␍except:print(f''=='-'and 241or 1);'''ssss';@'
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1_1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM  e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
'w(WWW;wW;WW;Ww;v;;wW;Ww;WW;Ww;vw;W_;WW;wW;WW;WW;WW;Ww;WW;WW;w;WW;WWWWWw;;;WWWWWWWWwwwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwW\WWwvwWWwWWWwvwW/Ww\WWW ho ho ho ho // ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; ";echo 350;exit#"; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;#{IO.puts 295#';  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68'))); [exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';          # wWWssss {}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__DATA__="""  
#"  \
__END__
se pr'[puts 59][exit]:;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2#
#  
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
#+------+XX   X       XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X
_|/1001 | 
_|/1000 | 
_|/$001 | 
#+------+  [``]````
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  x  x x  x  x  xx
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
write 224;bye; 
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
 ( *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
  
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<  
> 176
>> Output 1
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-}
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code}
ppppppppppppp;
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
#n::=~147
2k::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit

:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit

#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__

#}}} }put$343 {{{





































































































































































































































































#//-->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<style>
head+body,text{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}}#~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
#85""C""Hata>;re^;s0::&&1Pr"9"pullasgeEx Cr Uithary,"t."F _giogrlopstdisp[]!!92[]?42>80538在ｕg=1\0C0-<?ML5:
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:"\??-"[1]?218:67^*u""):*u""?37:z(0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  + #.---.>/
#s{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &  g+$
endif#                A=AgRA;       AC                      $p/
# {                      >001kk1;@,,,"370_";# _"582",,,@   @,,,"364"<      >"473",,,@\
""";'"#{'#'}'}'#'        ^z;@,,,"366";k09<      @,,,"369";@,,,"372_"^ s;k-109<
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )9
#<<<##>␍'@#'''
#ce: s~##                  >0k;"'3,'7,'1, @'763",,,@;z"482",,,@  @,,,"368_"^;^;k09<
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe          ^># 001-:2/_;:^_!k1"923"3k,# @#_+1y2"982"2k,# @#;# k 1;^;# _ "UDOM"4;@,,:1';# ("373",,,@)
#\!|!o51   ;        ~nJQ  p'34'  \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#print(47)#]#echo 21#>/123nnn; :/aa*7+42@n;/#print(171)#s-#print (365-((1/2 )*380))#s|#print(208)#sCOMMENTprint ("65"  )#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeee^ee*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"                  <e 5>1  *///         **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpULdIigRAgG9SpEqlUt3S7aqrakl173WTLBZIgiRKIMACSIksSRXdnt1et@2Z9fS0J9ptj2/bs55trydivBM76/aOPRNh78cJx3zyDyg/NjYcG@5/0HvOSQAEJVKqao8jJjYWEoFEPk6ePJl58px8HHR0b/jTn8bwYs8caz6wnAmbGN6E9VzzzHBl9mDO7uuml9eygoCxdt3BdGTYE68ixJjKmKXbg6k@MFjftCaGm2aeYbCOYTnnEK4xtj21p57Rq8NbljHbOGcHdtfsAQQ2cU4N23xjuBCWY@yhYV2OLies64xGut3z2Ng17QmF5hl7psNLf9o9ZXrHm7h6d2I6NgQVGHtuW/qo09MZRR@7Bk9UZACqe0pplkNKjD11XM@AHJyu4XkOepbBU3dN58nupx9fi69m2Mc6IDW2jNm17FWVfW4abu96Co19dvLo0XXfLPua5Njs0U2U1BzbnU6cg8l1@Hm2OzBsnWlyWdauBxaAmBPDKmVKmetBRahPY2J2l/KBgEemC7Wr@7XIuroNtYV1ucWM0XgyZxKvf92ywrr1mO6xqTfVLYpnT0cdww0iehPdnZj2gJ2bkyGbDE0vTEexvbHeNaSeYZkjc2L0mGVCIqfvQwHQdo@dGvNzx4Uq92E6tjWHhEbX7JuYJMADAOKVmAwNDmekz6GS7Qk0DqYzD9CwjABaUohB/IdGZzpgznQynk4Y4NYzPb1jAdDOnPWMvj61JmnWgTAgMvmfDw3bb8wATgYQJw7H6tWUUDMWbV7v9VgG2jHgcWowE6hGaFVYNgv@zHGBahArwMgHRu2al9GYQZ1BFfWdCstnMhC@H/ogtrrlOT4yy6hhoA19leoM4T5znYGrj4AaPYNo@tnBM@Z1HRfe4IdxeX@6DUxXn7DtbRbf//RhnNXDapHdjhBWUY1dQBXEgkB2pltTaCHRmnCgftwwtYBVFt@IV1gcyKJlWC7HctBtS0zLA5HUTBkc0P@1rAq/AtNKLKdCD8rH05hP39UHpmVwKAOEUsSGr@WZBvdMjmXVEo85cKw@j9alzIosW2KFIivmWRHuZVbWIDcEnWNqOQ@/AvwAWhlQUeGXzXFAi3YP7RTb2h7r6yPTmvvQCXyX5VVWBIiArwqQtRJAgGc2i78s/Ait5SsKezIEag/1MwAvWeYpciMjZEhYhQo8lK0thTgislyevTfE7IF0QLR8iRUh@wJQIgcoAGW1EmSfz/CCeEPDsvxkQw@TEbbFDPwA8yLQoQTUzwAtM0jMIvzgHfidBoxNAy6mAWPSgJloGrizmAXEK0BYAaqy4NNrqHunkBHPR@sR8YGjAxgVqY1MTEUiAQSoLZaFOiuwHDSELDaEfJYB/oBLscCAj5VUVsqxUpEBPcsZBnWjAl7YSlTgnyrgoyIwqH8VGoAKOKlAbRWAqtk8EyLEVrMYDmmzkBZIo@YgTQ7cUHFqAX@QDlqGClmqkKemlReNEHDT8lDefJZap1aA2i1CGNBNA1w1aE4aYKuVIBzTloCGJWy8xXiaE0JHOkCtYHOHdgjEyAM@BBfiglsrZjn9dGs81DvIrXnKTh@TFrAbFJCMkDSDxYNnDqkJqGQADPYCQF@DFpAFcmSharO5MHtLBSANBG/0TGLQlgm8Sw0pVExTg3yljycLsqkFwmg8nwxDP437OcA4TWB@xkDvzsNA6H3pMHDhW8iir0a8dgEok0NfDzirM/WsBZDQkdMoK@PMtBZ@JfLrGXqvb3rDtwtcc5RJx9Antnm6yCWfT0eIqkcCChiw5FXMRuNOTAmGq8EQXYuyaEWMM3bCClpCWVUJvY7Rn9oDQyqXIvhRyGTqTmBgWeRZ5t6uORjAmLyAo6apmDRQLrzzhKGVzU6E0BOpi3m6Jgzf91h3CAJFGFjm8MvlBYyshjDmegdHdQmkMBgFyjhu9c0Z69zr0qixQDBLdOoOzXEQubI2cqRyKZNZqRBpG0S5N6VMyJrxasmvHNNOxFk8KVwJMNZwyTI6UsOA9jmOUjjuYtOFcdUhqWHBPhN2MDImgWjLgzyMuhawUaiUro4jMI5HBo2nARxzIjPIBMRAwzlDsZUGxaVsPBo4Oy5KqSDl9AzXZRgXRFsvTUOsN@14xuspylELvPowZhswtPd10woRoHFEn5AAAM@4B/nNl9Huu86IBpsRDqGW44zXiCswYJ8joMfOubFAfTGe6@OxBVIT@BtcaANkznWSt0k4j@bKEYJEmA4qHABSViBtmK7RJdr7RYfUWZBLllGsMK1@L4tQHkTEqSx0FhA1PExjTy2rAnKO0WXZutIzzhT04SLXsqiFOARCGIhSPoiODrIyYk5YhJDuaTKJdydBzXrOaLlofHw9CIs@NFEwss71OdReH4ZWY6aPQKJnKDZDz2UjaDG8BrEmQGfBYh2wnmPHJyGUcxeEWCh0WBISlJEmE3NkgPbjQBKs8RwhjaM7YdaZQ1MmauVkUnc4JtcIJQvXCcU9chEP3llA3OtNu0g1zNu0qQWBmOShjO8Cq@R@wsRlzaYOPxfkubGv4cnowIjHiFpEQfB4b/cl7y5BRBnVsD1QKzyZmah/QcsfOH1obOcmlB0YFiRdwO4SEZAEoddM7soCkRwb0OjUYibrjscM/GFQgub5KFMCEdR5ZbI3EGgNQYXoTl13zmZjqAlzBLEmXaffh9b7xhgPAQQb9Vh33oXuCZWMrUfoOcRguuPlYi7eNg2IY6NSsvfs59nAALKDwNpH7RSb/KIA4zEVgUih21yYtXWgFBahO54TWYTYIkXfcWT07zmGR43FcU/Dro@ZecaAugb0s/6CGY1QOIdWapNS0QPO43cvhI8ZCisLg1n5reBjw4au04VWCZ0eqg/rdJf1QcmOiLCoZ@jdrjGe@O3EIXZm2hF5//ARyvvkK/nAZG8obN5n29daDUQNW05ElkX9B1Ef@2qIjrzW1@QlEjxClZNzFmt@I3uIcXYtd/ElxlnC4KW4BocxdQlUfohJTCfISpA7mt0h8sIJchuSt6G3udObxQe/aPbuiEn9MG/ERgW2I8hK6IV4rIchwc@6CUgeWwirvuSBUZc87gCte6MVkJ0QSasX9ZUVXQameBfQkWM7K6ACMUO4GGU5hOqCGuMxcg3dChsjdRdvqY6QYS8ml3AggzF0PHZc6Bmc6cxpJoGqLNK6fAU8EY4VSZk9WB5aYciI44A/wVEQEowtHdoCdjHsqaBZ6cApgIlxBRl4nsNzjCBMvZ5g@fidE@vnjQnGUts2UDnT3TkHAsWD4RkymjPTdYENnuEgwcegYDCRqZ3CmKD3eshZkRzU769nLmOL3pt2zNl1LbyLnvIrTzjTXdZHBdwFoQM6USLe9@LJKvlTykiQqDjjiUJJ@V2EiBRJhipP9EGnh0HiETCa47ndTYhLXUxMM3E66ZfEJDgwIZfR2CegKlzHDtUHbDSjU@jX9FZlAxi@JQnuEvoRJhigyBiguyBnQCcELbNc7nV0dgncw2XSbI@rIoFKosq5MC/D7oV5@YRAXKLllXkWntslhxQZ1bAEGJ1KToPEEgHfkxKUUAQPRfHHVvQgaY@HkVzDPac2zcOxBBdFkuwiFH5hAEgQMiYIH2bXnLR9ceXevUBw2ajVoLGBNAVss5eMarTBhKUMnBoiyySN@JnIE@d4gn0jkYTyYuQrjg2ITdBSa3V2MRm60OPo/UqASEBWwcaWHBDWr@dPzdNp73pF2@iJkUTsdSA0md2JWBVg8Oe9oXYbVeNLVAWtN45UxcaL6Qn0jcZLvlihoh/NNTwUf2s@KpEaTiAGfltdSSKe1PdbNOi9edfyRQLugs7OuVEH0D/1J7JCRpT2ZYKg097oqRwIdgcOhz3bPXlc8/siD1Q6pl1Z8rCcrm6R9yZGF4O0Tw4eHO0e/Xx7BQzL7FSueyhmrlTAoXY6kwb2VMnJWmUzCmMB@GH7dtiYcDmOKPjBTHJmEVFp3oXBZRaQ8/Doa9dJApIQkoNyADf@rok0PA4IXUJH94bXBmE2SKUgyzBJEJdJByyAGToQdQzXA3yeTd@8wcq7jtTY90fMrKnOAQSeyoEdpJMx8JoAFgR1@nxEpLQghZo2LjQsXNGYAT4fo9R8HRkSpSNN5uPDR/tHNQLrz6tJFEXxJiBL6W5PhjZvTUEFXxUH2B@4uiwlLxBHeZpwXUngbneJwIu6ZWvgAwDUdWSHSdYoKJo3BNz3rpeNfKVu2ALonSBclyuj8lD3QxGN4IFDXBdV3lWjKAUsBqvQa@WIFYYuD1vdfN4o5srRYau7yLMXBUqLAjAOBHKjC0GnnoQ@8kKK9MVqH/3jJzcQ90iIBFVACjDzLCZTXp4loPYimSzuKXugoTmWIX9OHE9kYlJR4sG6gNz1SPmMxN@fmZNEJsmfahLiQu67uwfawyCyP2VNMxmkNKAujiOT28f1va4HbcR2LGfgsC1Iw6XDIEMQm9YWc3fg2DdqSEdPLGoMlwiB/@LEjT6GscZ8Q4ojpYqqq3yxUbe9c@DSaiGLRCIKESiF4suv9DMdyLUo9/HBN/ZhEFHzmUzoztAFJIikIXKhqxvxJQ8mQUayj8/KAobLhTd6exAgRdbrsNA@owsT7i6CV3oSx5SVlfFXovSJc4Pir5z5taYFPrxpgSNCsoNPnz05@HT/6e4XzYmWzy@95zLlAhAO8uuALCQPOd2wt27xronFQnAx6Bsudi/gAlNQUILVoqnnAuOWMYrMEVjTavhCa@ITZ2jHveT1wpxjqPTK7vIm9BQ7H4/qJwRFu2ehMuLy1Wocz7H9DCeTsVdRFOjlw2lHBqVVedV1LH2gUDoYGCxLUVF1OTjEeQ1vVQpAxpsbPAWf3ALRYU4ziLo1ckB5oTVvZA0swcHTrJVlDoagC@PCuOEm5bAFU2mUHmgIoCsrYdmIAdMb0NZ/BvUk8qb9VVUr8XatZrScIgbRlro/xN3oG6A6JWC0AlIkr72y5r3mPTYHLo2QrgOJMXmLJjk8hmOBxUCQpFlT1PMD4hC3wPlS5BVEo9dTnM0FLqXkM7miWsgroJaBmgYyq4RzbtJIn3SH0sSRAJ7k9GneINIK@15Xt/vylu8IkAW57yMoarbxotm0WyCgN@8Rbrju3Ji3GmorWWU3k2z58ZNVaL1LxcO2G3hA2yUnNE16sjX8rKffZGc9nXpXjymT0dgfc6Qxe7oLgtQbB/h1z4j2PUygRAOVraW4CkZ@q6yYELIwqYA3pJQCHQpGWmh6CuIlgdCL4iG0HOBbkQRsMZvBy8H3d0T4CCrd2O5NJ@7RGgnKNThb6o2BiDTZ3EUu7eH84ARGx7DlI5eGykUmzc6NOM6j6x6frYRE/hp/kB50tRACzcqHM9J2uKsBGgGlIvUcOAe0K5w2HS5mGVHph5YGGRJOOPkAEoRNqwcD4DOQmBdklxeE50Q@y0U6tZ1zG6F1DFaSOuaET/Y7UxfXus1etGwQPavxOACNChfh67Qo3jG6fJaVJ6ZSgBKos5ExcnAqAaQrYgUGFUHnC@qoC3o4Yw3dKiPhiiHAl9j9PeBiXYPPF0kjVKKgSe2z@MRVdqVvKLr0BlrzLbIVFj5SxX6lnwQEWN7eQLMk/gwoSSfOiCJ9TvMtGPggEHcFXDGEEkMLE/WaMzbs6zof1wgTySptQ4jH@SLQRXxjYyNeidfjaXDtgGsbXTvoSoFrh1wSuTCejC5KkSYXhjYoBfq14leNAPIs2cI2MEPJ4Y05TuiNSiXbSusN1X9q@ExCVQDlIbaED4ATT9Zq6Ewmxfo5rtmA/B4p@x62neOua459EnwCAgF/92mQJSKAeo/SvGtUUTe9nSKjmgtKo4EiZsKNNxuZZqt50eylmlfxNKZOVvUa6IfAvCaJkTxwnekYBLdGriIBb0s2spVWtVOLZ@JbiURJsiAjPZn8qJRM6ZzWibgBbSrRbMaBpD51Gt2hS/BmaS2ZDAkFePRN0DIsKxGXL0qQfyfZSqbikDYZTwNbrsXjQBdacPSo0DgjwBvRI3MGpISOCUNcdE2BGCQtTmF3/YYxHs7daIRw1g2kbJxBX@xVwS09yMWjXPINTx8V6JY0/UDu5fFAuMXJO5SXxnPO3QWOaVNZ2hkVjLtnUn/kTHTlMxmUJjkyXMY34ookwUhIIRwSFfup6WEX1m3DmXrRmcaVE6CYO/ieDKfALIPtaWloVeZYMLpDh8U37wN0Fq734FCCS1cSXwALAPS6MvyQiaJUgoslIF3QhiIT@CJtxaJZGZWQ4KwnmJvPF8av5TC3KqVhGczIHNiOa0hAEkgh0O4p2pMn1IN16QOa@bqxLuGH0pCGirdpAEd8ZDk60Zaz68h60HgUSQ/6OSQ5MnqCBfyjD@xR5nXhGj1lS6BVWscdwggBpUFOrIW1NfIDFMcb9@TJDJIKCRxwo4FcuwOh85z1NE0rdPP9ShCGrQKIPYRKQq3UBhU3CJJUCEz6lbzPp4UCHf3Tw4f7fO6EBlscXnEerT1yelOQK3296ciwB2m2D@3JtJ2RCWQI0r85tY4cZ8K1fHhZNzPDlWZzNLV0mvO5Pi1za7qu03Esmgq6Leki/tT1dEvnk1BB6O5nT0HWf35yXJMrkUiKfja6NW@ch1ydLafnQXTNkdZbg@UhjzdMcTMv4rgV7PpENuMHFDBg6u/5hDoK/IvoH3QpXEPx/UvoP8L9niAr@7MI9Bp6@hHLFBH3gOKGN9/zQs1cof9aHSyMp1I8LjgusL1QNfI/m/T7S95Z8j6VkDVZC@8cefO9oEs6YhSlPI@EG0OX4kQBFShOuD90bbwixeO7W@RwZfFpuAlhaFjB0uIRSCy4fAaDvoVyFSgtKKLzPZwGSNhjXCUh1o1rb6wLQqh3Yz4DOttY4rGF2AZ1IBjcFBRphE2F@XPfVepCtuOvWXqcrTqg89O0ynadr3KjTuVydU7hs/KbbQCxXa8GG@7WRcOc4vEwGkEl3CAFFZMW9m8UNdym4dFku0BJqoKngDox0zJSc1bcb13GFY/I0Gdiszn7KKN9AXoJ7pbcvKcMjCrtcVpDr2oQEvdl2M6cSSDxYSw@cd0dAp9hqdkyKaF@pnbfsXoSXyWDBsO4foUV5G9SCHdx@pt1DdMNNnDSDlqeFPlrZO/nDbjXqrR@M0Jkt2gICLrPBbs8TZ9dsgYMeWeyN7bMSYtdyROnPfR3StnX95VyGdR19bkn@Htcamz36OPPGpkWhyCMdFz5KvFanAXbk0FwBkEJ95GDC3fqTMwJSQK0E8HE8qoyIDWjRRJAH2DwDKoszMgvEaJ@aVwuytI3QFNNGIi5Nx@lmZG8kvuWPpkYNm9zfPlxPbn5OpGfTY2y3/EXHSosQyszIJmaGAYoVtnxycP9oyMZWq6XiO/jCk4FuqPeHYKAsq7QASWjha@wj3px9hGmSaLaLkBXA@2j7aeHRl2FRg/6B@SOvGNguAnwTOLiSxe8ab2LEnIJzScQ7rfqTohGIbCEkYQyEbDKSvyf21zV8vGsQItPESWB3Il7FaCtmZSntvla9mCgIbkVosS5sgrjRW0zQVxsU036G@pGuHQMGhYJjVCCRoNJb4DLQWSRtVpVvgcA4qIC5g6QuqJIVUG72GtqUPU18AaRhiD4yWtv2YtGRiq3UpurQNHmMn8DOi9/BC5CWAbtGSuz3UxQf7/RkTkOfC2Qc@7npE5fO31RYZvcIfI5Z4oebJgipkP7q5b3SS3vwoJOhqyEpmKwIAFLiPnHA/w2S@HE@UHnwWTkkUiyi5DoGpKcXV4SDdmmxoiG4FIZr4yrQPsExvTEgdI88Y8GRKUD6q3@RhLss01BDNSs5ZVaDOEivHJ2TTqVzsRoOi4dmvapQ@s9oaudkdU8SoRh6tGpdTMlbkKl21LUEAceV1uHnTfq9Om2IgIte/gL6uRBE@q@LAxCpK4c0YPm1lfkvLyJZClbf3sqjbTgZtLrO2JK5RJF7nc65rqoQATcFxY8V0QDJoXtWZNzshqcNcCpGBiPgHFx7WVR9Ov7j9gS3f19tP7zP3@zB/S/WTtDGChw5jF0tGHoxpqS@msry0@KL3RbXbF8gnxqmToRhlx3gezqLhRJt0LHatC0CC9JMPyPcEnBr3Fom3gDqfGWZsYx5yuCwXN1JqsW1Wxgmd11ca/tx@JZ0fIPKHY9IgIXgkyDEhHr4pVgzPgSTETFRjZ2N1LBpilGjZnX@3A6mfI7CK53VqI5xt9tfdOPmcnrHdVQ@M71W6rc1U@nPUcanw5CObWwIu6i9LQGLIE44C8Ht9G5uvi8gHwnePBcF20xtCnn9LirVXj21BtLHdLCe/yNOsLolhxci9/XRTH9w3uhYz3VTItu79kSfejQUPzdEAruNZUiRDOvkdnSO3OUQYYf3srCnQXAcWrdVCqTXbO0PB6vT4@aJKUvl1ennsldTo9VcwQK388q8Vk0KrC/w/WOWoXhyhzplqT1Is61zHzVxoQbUcM1TUqDhy/oBMatjRwHpO7U0t2F65YmvsAjWEZYNyPtDxvPzK4D4sCYqUVZ1YKhIzJgEMsMtsYtMsLtxHSLbH8wV5ExOE4iha7VLMDpTnDL6Jo29R4MjW/VxA2xkUYiO@so1XXO8bdWfBiCasrvq0e0Nyuxeg/mJFldS4dxfO1wsDQ5iJOPdzTUc9Mz6LaasKcrEZ10rZX@y10gmPaLTuPd1aw903I8dkz32wg0cIEK/L66QUdpaeq2RJPhUfctPCjY47CoUN0aOFahNFB0uK2t9anbR77vP9@Xw4UcSlXv4FCB@OPYqv9cy9dPFff0rgqiA4su7m@NOG8ZYlexKX/tZX3pQDHAhbvVJXuUKVFKWeFTfWsyxiWXc30ePH@GoWMdaYOhYzwncRqkO0xQLoFj4nIR@2fJLXd7br33Y0o3wBbvKkSkck8tAwYrut@oUqZl1A9MoWYy78@i@tbUmBorFY3DzisDj9XfomS8P1IZvxib/kw9Lg7g0ZQw1htfM3wvrHGcxrdbmYlumV3jblFmmamNQfoeo@r8DBzP0HEzxcCejpdqdUk7s49uJ9lwHHRpp7eEHYZ8KB8q3SEpLcnnnkG/WzUmruHhBrFaPpPJ@AJMZMVl6eU2TSobpn1l8vtSxuSzyHkRF1fZ3IhzdR5ElugWxLUsSFun2FPkclmxTduYzPH@nty04zjWh9QUMFU8MOyAtirRVtvbauyGuOMfImGLqQsPJzw6/XWTFny08XVLoA8qzbdVenRJ6L1qU8JFzxEuSC2/3j59E1lguisXPNyKc0J88621Xpb0Z0NUuSQXb@11XEJ1Ooal88eskLsNXlnO3gpvmWn4i7W4uMuXdBdL8bFrTGk8B2KZPdBShsbIoNdbpHy9hyYy/MfaSDMHf@uCZ4bRVWb7RnddhLEJfMHG@9IackRYmjg26FcT3OeHeoqFO0l933UcOFj1W0nkg5E@MLjNlts45WLCAnfTcLVu4Vw9dVHhO2i6kGxhjGN9k4BOdWrMveC5EuDTeRfqdTq6e7rtWufv4hzoe/T2dVtYbw6x9tAZ2kNjyPeNh2/rOge0xwm3sXMb6oD1YIhb2cbjpS3uUXpajmW9Dz2RNXJG6Tj9lTjt4@FXPLn1QXD5SXv/cefknT7hvAMda3vN0JjCuOQ5E2dsSPS2LqqFEz38vo6HBovUP@sM0q16PlAkeP6s8O/ULQe6MxmP6dEeW1OPbpRUojPLd8lNfb41hTZFOu5AfuOMOrLvKfv7VmgJfDWL6ZiT7hAPjfOWbQycTndo3oW0b6hCCaZ8@Ot76a5IGZNJD9FbtkwgrzuXsb3UouHH@DhYV@n@7BEf1kLHLfLKqhk6OpYtjfXTrsdnQ9HFKjghHOmN/PB2hY6/V15PzckCaGQvUzi9y5cl0LEOd3/3xFrJis5ILNiwv6tibSslIR0FcsnIgMCjrst2eZ9bpItls/y2DqFoKQmjyL6UDyG3v/eHZgfNyLwt@C@1r6VNSysHOXs4HXg3GSafru@BiIa39dMWtJc5MmUNY5Zu@491ZNYsBQ85wrMNMtfUuHVNJX/rogrFUy1Jd0x4tOEBVTddO4dmmWOP35nUX7sU5@9lAl38@nohp818tTLtV0zP6PMlEHTdJSKOHBd3IoMMInVxJR1n0JGZc8GLMy7bGQBTlyy2iBzEXSe2rNwmtLr6wzFT@uJTY6DjXusn5gQ3a65oFdRkV20vuhP216e6Z359CiVb19jQYgNfhnSjR/vxbQW8p/rA7D5eqogQSZ/A/k5P/lhq/uh1sy7Oh6aHO5pCxy0TU9jkeCPGVtcGvWFFzOvz9qGxikUH4scgV8ZeNbfujOd4WmxOrtum1c0JzbL6z3Wq47pNYLcicT4djaee/1iNA@2Zis5Cj07J3zs3Abj0GlgrG@rWZPVMdWTKFaQwf1BcONdJ498wLWfAvlHKMBDaQAhD4XxFw3kAw/Mz3JDj2itaIuX9nsueONEhubxgr6FujSyTTNuc3D6bM5ng5pzgiYXhIweeUFCe4F2@/6EQpJPVFHlyt6y/OJp8x/gOLe/YmbpdA52hvZGoWuDnauwFu4/xRIeD9lLOo1pa17Gge4HDWtlluo49nUju1L51VCjcOipU0NpUpBmwxNf3nz5PRlsD7da@SwoN7JEtXGs3DFxrZKYNgth6ProcO9AlHnI7SUe0VfiONLtozKlL7Pqhs0rfeTaHAeS9FSZg/tPRQ6OLy4Z35v2p89SxHRiNxsAoR0cGP/O/tNFjdUJM9gRPtQN9endmc0xg1wxCXNrQx0YH6tdauN5nLOKAH@oTfc1QRHODpP@Frjvbiml1DPcVTfpF3OtU2mWEHhsz0i3WNxjeB6VJt8tFYpyPW@ojSys23thxbH4nbpuBh/r0dq4CQwHd3n@hXMaN@EvzAiv1s@WiHp7xXSJGjxulWFdW1@g4Fr/fsifJNvmeAN01DU95gjYOyK@QYxJIX96tPKR4Kw9ZqEYgyZ7pHi3Sr1Y1FiDV2QdsARrqbtfBlTDfccvunIhhgjvYdLi3n28c6ADhZ8Cx9O7UNxZ6F1rWqDOi21qFIVKbR0YHTwV1yJrHRJ/drEw@M@SbMojs6AoNAATsCjt1gSWegTaSvHvYWtKjlqlqjulGnHrtcjlt1pFs0@i@0XHWzCF6Leaml8KhzMqn5FwzVx3pRjSLrOh00n1lT1reugYCjWVIk6ELOr8yuW16OzCzsmI9ZDoycJF5eRVmrejqeEMqrLN6PT1krq4h@bb@gJeEdv@4fCjtrpU8ETz8Hz74RIFBuF3IBaZHgHXdvYIPyE9d23@8Twt85niTvjk7BLzxFMA6doLFykMSePCega6tdYWA2rOnFp99GET2XY16pI5JZIVZkixi1xNDMuwziQzBzW6WyOGHvpRdtN47MXqSbwcBVxqkJ8H5rzCa/1yxgBrljbjZU1U4YWeFnL/9cxVxzwPOAPKWM5HGHj2Vsffs4MnhiTz21JXj0@4QT0fckOOWDCtopUxkSuqV7kbWO/l2tJ7pTZQHx6q09@RAxghr6M1XNCR44Mrc0mPtvGdgxVXR12pBGGpMVguIj0@ePkktjmiyxN7QdUZGMhq8d3ycxpMmnxyvDI6mfgS9o@/M1iY/2FfV5Irm@9ym1cF13HNFTusgnRigjUJjfMztstwpXHWdsdE7mY@Nz2DwRA7uvWf2hbWF/FQ/MwfYC1l5LaGoo7KyXMglIzuzQdk23PC5rj5PzTFyyy49FP5Yux0FJYes4mZXSw@3rfhfl2JYxt@J8GGJ1MzN1hq1I6zo3t8XMVVV19H5WO9DvbL82spajrBqfdhyzt5jKdnwlRcp9JIm0Kok88595EVpBKxbwRtOz/ue4Oys3QZzG4DQu7Cyw58b9ly3JVrLuk28qEBq3NR2a5RvGO@xIBXu8DlDY@Ur1/jCLfUs0SVn8o6MT9xIkr29Bwd3JTjyaXl7rI8/fc6e6R4aIbk9YhRj4z0wXkhGrySct0ILeGuXU3sugNJuhTcYr@7PFXasuz3Hns/uXoSjM6g4tJNx4RAWvlEkwzJn5qqxqsvntZ6t3mZ0V978EIczX5KDo8ZpfEDvvv3PVDWTIdND@FQz/PWOmgk6OEugS5@jPbto0MlByBq6KLfI4JFcqY0@MWa4HYXPBq9S6leOb4Vbxr5icv1wcltY6Zaw3C353QhDT5aVM@otAPO3hLG8HAY/cazzoSPv6a7hrdh/vBKh2wpSvqUg5Qh39q2l08Ki714v4uPRBf@xsrWeGBM3Nx46HTO3sgy7fTQyyZ6isfSb4f52Ct2l7S0Dxz/ywd9X53c@NVZm9FR/szqAOM3pyiBggsZwSkcibgYvL5B2QOY17IHJ7SuyB85kn95uUczCE8@r9yKY44fT8XqMgTfiJymus/OliJ@Dzuyce@wBHo1biOkrdH/cH7faf51My8KJQTQz@vhkN2hdh8eKFslxgcUXz5a88fDo5PA44ucas9k6pVeardMhV4Yscv30JLeU7Xb9xdkKYq0/bwTiBvDj8LlWDuLM7pPjmywB1bfhZGQFIZ/o9mLGdKnCes6EThquDHw2n9E2ypU1PeS72FaFud0V3kuKPQzIpgl5e0q7jZb12@11rfLE@ILWHkAMYhMulnCgvuElY5YbBhhSkrUd1TldCD9L6B6Ph6Y9Wxk0WpeGdpEmXnmru8EuO7acc/YktCq0jj1oq4HrZ4a9jjmtOqwolbO3S2HZayLVunrhXy/xH@uq5ME6Qe0az8ANEbdxE0x/1FUeBS@fack7439yHES/O@6e5eD8fc@cju6OTGBTqbsjurewv@sAzbuj4cc@ToeOa98dNWhOlcoD4z2R2Fgfkx9EhnYcNWLvpX0zRPzgPj8u7cnBlwYSCRtIlFz@rFP07Deaek5soqnTTTrnDXEvL9mGf7YaAsTgtLZ/mhwtIpr21MDj4PxjL5PaJmRTq6n5MtvB7yhVQJNLUo7oRXbngrwabPPCPyhdqahXbKPGxIrI/KPqoRlpbgoZ4KIRVygTk05VtjmBkM3gmDWjr3qwS0azQ6COqvkMvMlK1OBE1T@IDihtXjw7eLZ/fLJ78vy4kWld@QfVg0LYNuQWmMP4KNsToew@2UDq5IbRyUCCBdnRF0dwVskLysXwK0bLRastFW1RKHEH02xe2Lai0Fl9RboC/CSR50ahyDvBi8MOSkz145tpqPBj83T6H6qIgxYpT6izCsusynisgwS1afvh1z/6RaH4UbgKfhYOM/ZtWUNDHDhOz8/RM9jdV5Djo92DJ8@P9lmA4KLRnJu9ybBWznNT59x@CNRT36TNizUW95PEoa5qtfijOBAmLsdZhawrkJlxaOcQLaAO2mXwU2@xxCbBBwrGw0pR/vM3lau4jPvwkxA3HiAVh2yhyVND2djYYCfQSNjDo4PP9o8Y4r//kLyRRAiCneDR7j/7UY9/qCMwvRR8EM8dkbhDpmuEqHmHwObBwiwD0py67nj9Z/Howxhk/CD8Ikf4SSFBoA@2QLs9J6uJ1yzqJcnIFf@Mn2/wMMiImlBg3B@XfNB4oeuxM9Mz0fQC4tBHW4LLjR13iZH9TJnt4jf/8MuCOn01BlCf2hNur8u32hODliaHLCfNNglZ/o0ZMRIxvr0Bjb1jgCTMPNsEuWpSYa@gJeKySoWb5pCkevxGkgB0hVwSSk@RiDeMD3pK01Xe/eo/UQZVBu4JuL/ju2eZB/D2y/5bH9y/wt0vFGxoN40VLnCJIoQGRv0ScERC@iPtI586tLk5lAXh0KZiwFeZOYJqOiOqY3SeA79LwI4XcBKNz6DSoLlBjflmUHh@httKoIXTiqJgk0LtTKZDKMaM7wi9Zum0kC/kVAWQlM4CgPRpggEedecAk8kKdBPhzBzXXoLEv729zUScojFqhSqvWWXTfpEVX4aIbkJc4XyIyDUYpIEkixQQVveTweCTUpOYFLlXXI0j4@o5MCpROI5e@G77hBBZAojFaWSgrfsZfhVzAoKLb7G3g9@RjHy2ZtMHJKkwJpErKQq@AZFPnQk0H@ikiw9TcQMiuCOaj4BoCtPj34olQ7nYHuWbPWtx7j34Po7f12TkARxUNnN9MI3Wrfg5gjhGEBVxVfNtvGDNSdNuKbxtMmimP1zRmG1w/5IyWNNmebl3b5pJTVw3corEYvePbQfnoh5BYVhCU7SsohaSiyLlciuL5JfIzwaKg7aYLiE7YFPAMrqG@coZe7t7@wefHD47vmEKlGLGr0cDvl/fTjUlOd1ohY54tFjLVfLgkXL89MGjoCIWSBci3BgYv18S9baSLKaYEeTiyNL1oq3C8Hrp1mP8OTdqcB3frHYbapToBh5q5gPypWMD0iM6/Hc9c620ilr5/G0oLeApEdB7/OT2DVQTyYurRmu73rRj8ZstYUVHeBGTt7ATgKvpbW0q2NhvFg4LFn7F@QS/j@dF@2J2dV8UN7NoaQ4NR0yc04UtPt8jEhApb5ANsEhBVoKoa3vfIZfRFxYjNf6VaW6iLmqAK4JwIXMbxSOgToIPViMXWdi79U29DnVvaJkdITB8xk2@BpYpQ2uv3GhZIin4X03hGSf8T1jPKjOZ9ggmksjtCFaa3WY9NoCXFKBDo3T3bApq@jNnzK3o016Qh0bgOnKA/T6c8rkjg30yHUG8Pj2ODFqXA84tQWKgZDxElctSwCV847GzFJrnhfwaaELWL7g86uUTs6Q8NGY9cwC8PZFMA0f7SFVbLDQwi4Umg7J2XKQ6W9TCrV3xYzyPHyX7B1kZni0Q0Bu6bNo9Y5aIn8eTlRbkj/7x88/P4klxVVsia8e@@d/edbPHIfpF9XZOok/83hnYFF7FLcrlm1wC/K4D5ub3gk94lcvy0BPok4w1lNyPJ@4TcIIYkeiP9DFLTG1uulBm9JpoJuw02XST6twsqs1SKVKo4EEBMqOUfXLx8Tuh23OWUGr41U7w9ewePt6YY9ZQZbkFbsokyTbx03p7IHGhMc@kADowJKkQ2Bo2IVAzACPeSWTewCENhkNceJAByBXB9KUxWr5wkCZUala/xyKfSlyWHMVyueJX6DJXLDNofTfZoawA2Bt8LpDrgbq@VSOgGai/shBbMPKbHC9G@cY4Io99c0iATixiyjiwksQA1sLQcHfo4i@xb0NfAfmgUnl@8qhdSioiC80qDVyzh8tr3Bp/qOL530@CbqosRY1XuUb3MSZDA5ZtbrcJ7Sg@og4jXmOpsSgZfCPAgbLsLdqmqt7a6v2Efi1AzBwOAP7x03YADo2OBvNuK8JWM/uf/jSGwkZiU1VP2@5ZKp7PVOGmVvMszz7abErSZiNTu7@pgxY1eT1rgk6ubOUenhnDfu9goDRFkWVZTlG2Li4u4o@2npkv8qwg9Uyt8Ho2v8oWsq9nV1m19Pp0rBYa8utZSyzV0qct9uzZF2/bb5Pi7Gz@WmwmtNje4aWo5lDlj1XK7GKnkI2dlkH9hHwZO2Vv4DrtM/wn95texK2ju9MHFTYuslizCRRXxaKoKI14C/5J3X8JF1f8G3W5Lu@03r5NNnR9Mpsz0zTHXq8HP2cIEqSWPGagL98DTs8TKKxJT9Kg8BrN@jfnE/KMzXaNwWC6r9c1PJks329X5@b00eTpNz4Prud4vTmKJHvjf8s3lUpIUmPFPEWlredj@FXgP/vxxlX64ll7@8@@NVKMDXwc4uM7V0/RfazmP9rY@OjBg1wurWkadz/7xrOf393dzT1M55818js5KbOx/ad/srGhaduastHyPLUVb5yefiFqmZwo/9nvxNvPnn3d8@rZ//Obb@sq3opwO2NF4BNwZZkKTryX4KeijPW@V@xNDFq5GpvTXzsW@F9sMLW@U/wv3zt8HZvE6pryuQvPSex1rFCKcSc44C0bvJ3F6rFtjFa4is2VWq0GzuJ/@beQvv4JwMGQ@Tbc6vkAVmEeq0s1SnIZqxfAoWoa5Pt/f/ObEQw5m6iRGBdc91kDLjFX1MSdFlxbdG0LaK5SyihKEM@eDCeGw9TSPfUevpjwAg/bQLv/xqQZw@@is8P7jB01UqlUS25LcMkvaJJIUVWtqar3gB1IH23VatIW4wY5s9n8PTQqnqQprYEDI6Zx7/N/iCu2yrP6M4M7EmKFjfsvH9brUKZsPbtVT9HldyTqU8WS6Dj3RZZmL@OggjRaL58wbkW4LmZKmphOp@@36X2GtJJmYUvCi99jsdAHuyy77reUBKL4vrEPjxfbx@vP/7c///6ff4/@vk@//4D2PO2e2Ve2INIZdIk6XPcrlW69LtZd8aKJ73VoR5lKqVJS2lfNxBZwoNYRUzMfX8bz2fgx/2a5ylgzSanhomzrfvb4Xo8tvOvcpx718wN4ZPJgfinIsUQ1codUuxEPhlZ/57PUOKu3JBSIalJDLeRbEk9VD64ya9yHahK1Ylls1bW8dsjut2f8YsNNjzkx0AwLAR19fOuLstXDkMVbPeoVqwfJ6os4HxovxFeINRpKy6ABIfBj9zcqG6VKoaIp7fr6C5pm9JWiGobxzIudxcKLUza2IGgsbJrX/YKqCF9Y0ILZh8QDyeh9mC/VUragilXfpbWZWIVGomUlbdAWM6oY9jac34drA/7oH67wFe8b5ON7U5Sb1warqFtaVsl/VNjXcHy944riKsA4wbqdTudNtwNSh6539K6uTvSpPtPn@qQz7cw6k@60y7DLLM/oZ528U3JmjDdAWYpl8@pm7B416reNDXbEuVCLpYKrmbrzei7Lbd9JDgd/kuTMYkLsH@Cqq5rKtmB8ysANhDJygs6Mf6oqsBgIWhett1uNt1vQQeupbWKOrbrkYwkPuX2/lZKurhrgrlb9/@166KzSxV1QuNZVKrX9og7Sx4t6IwUgX/ggZYkRULldb21TSJiZn5sfvN0C@UVKbTe2a84e/WTqIFI858QLzv0WAN5eQvb@/ZQMrvsAoL4J/TGZSm1K0gaOjQ1/rIDIrXoqKBXikABp4eLiZ/yBoge9@Gr7qn7V2L662t6G/226X/lP8L3avvFPj8W1Js4ivIWspdlQ6k2l6TOLFrzLSh19ZKUJjjo8IV4jq5VaDXTAJbf@2/yX04t76IMot2TAWohtsa0YWpfMxraE2Mt3X/4v@Gu@@/L3UV5k8GdUhNgFdmtlC7XNMlc64cbspzZ7yi8b3PgLXtEHPZ7W0dPmNxsXpBTlpcwqfM4/oZYKSRkH4LbTb6PBCpm9hKg3eB8TtVJBbKfUucZi22KhSOzu525c8Xj8H73UysU4n6hBiwsvPc97GsFygSdErmoZVVIv6/yjAvz7Lz@36vpHP7fuEmKXZWZUgD5dj3HKCDFoSDFFkSQYserbI9yTj2slEqqlZ7UvpOe7Es6j6BNaCevyOYLawX6tXK7zZZ7NZ9Rtth5uwV2F//0NKAdr9iFus1/rjkACbvazea2JJuhjUuc1/j15g3/spIt/R6/xj528wb@jCf6xpx38O3mNf7sd/DsZ4d@D1/j39A3@PR/gX/Mr2axaFTcviDQptaxebc5EIlE1tlNvfmXiziuWYTfMXsv/ulI2V2bJWPMrxqxrjCcV7tmP/@S73/pWvFaLS3H6Zk1OdVymJqtAfSiRF6/ejwuxGttUN9WMlelm1I7aAYfJMi7LDDNDtQeKSltlGYNl5pk5y4wctQcuA/4y4DIzfZYZsIydsSEihIJr0s5M0NWHxwD@@gDIhT8Tt5h21EyXQUYWCm30uUsED67LdlNosDgTXxqga8qqnJELZgs/EtQQX75sKlstrVxiMjYqud142Yy3xKaIhuO1co515sZG86UIQ3NG5I0PfVjM80CBrcaUZlPhZAIKEBWvrtrt/U8fttsKDkPNp87h4v/wcBR9vfV/dOg8PXRGDvwfHh5C1zHqqfspYND379eAYfuPnVi9utOsENsPWH9M2d5p1rMSugsp4OYa@qU@8FpAhGd9oynEzxOoe5yj@lH9/Lx6ViX3efAKjnZ1ESGIxh3@E65zGOICdeQcrrNzdNAbOs8/b4Yu7lA@PwevzxnoXeE/KHjR1/8K/@Z/W/9Pn7MkSzRaycTF1XaCriT@JZMXVxdX/r2eTCT8l8Q2/KEHvGOSi6s6OinSBbgaiWQreXXF/eCeSG5zgHXIZrtOaRfxYFiIhVlStvyW@K/7hKz9qxmvgtzLdet8hvpRTKwyfbGvptmcZTLJaif4JgauEuuXtHkhWaUPIm52GmrrT3@Hvnuyk6RI@Vy1qm4x/qLltGo1F7wVS9VqKXjZTCTKN696ZkctgP6RyyWT1Sq87ARgM/AKaRvsbYrVWBPurXv3eCYl7fIygJnNFVIZNYOpg5zykK3h6V2f4V4cHNInQ4DV5GP4rR7OShIZ@uAQftQuLlbEe/cSPQP3Mfd2dpP37mnlzOVl6DMeg5e65NVu90y33Ub/7OWl2BZpH0w5D@@Z0uWlmimn1HjScROf4tcQIauEpLKPtDrlWgY2ruWKEOwjkN/eLuTq9UIOfAqleBLX1BuIfgvwjYvxqhi7oDKopSLngGIVvaP7g6Av46DALq5iVKEsl08mgJEmQQa8iuGfizyXDzf5fBIocyXymGq5zKMmWa6QKKXK/l9tA7RyEHL4H0pq2VRuq7h1H2Re/PNmqy7kydULo6Ze1S6MCs6qX1W7/nel0eyGce9etgwkKmWqTaHdfrh7sttu10RRREEJbuhJ3F1AayRuvEElz5dbnCKV6n2qZrWUZ1CfPI4UhxGClYDoiraVV0tIJMHso1UdIInAtaUNtiFo9MSbUOaU2wBPUGcg8x5crMc6bIAXG6Dyxkxm0cUsxsPp3u2GkRx@@aHhK6Ul/S7wMcJL8HthljdRGMSfPdnd2z9Ja9sSi2mPdvfS2vHzBzEVX/OLdwrO4vvR/u7Dw@eQ4NmT/d3j/Y8PPtt//gz8PXa@uAKm798Xz6hrxfs5@1x45b7RDUM3pobRPp9Oz1@zV6bZNqEyrSkUyhm4zDPaUJaxvihXFX5d09NfvdLdMV3s3Q@//e6H/9273/7uu9/@9rvf/v5Pvvz@t@H3I/h9lz@/@2/Kebz/5Mt/9rvvfuu3wfM/wO@P4Pfjn3z569/kP3r/Y/j9p4jfH/u/SDz@EwDWL//ky@/9zk@@/JUfwO9f@r8f3Pz96o9X/77/C@t/mO57v3t7nO/@W/j9HocVxP3ub3E/fN6I/1s83q/84N2/@Hf8/0/9P3T@9rt/8cd481/@6Q/@9D@9@9a/17TSn/7rd7/wvXe/8K13v/Cdd7/wj7V3v/6v1Uz09rvvvv8Hf/WHv/dXf/g/0v@P6P577/P/7gf/9C/@17/43//iD/3fj@H378D147/499BV/vYPfoj/3/uDv/2jH@L///yv/vYPfu1vf/l/IsdvcMf/8y//Db//9a/@x7/5ze/81Y@/@Te/9uO/@Y0/@Kv/41f@r1//j3/93//@X/@Tb6Hnb/z4r/7ol//yW9/@y1/453/5rS/X3L996/3L9/D/8h/A5/3xfB8471OuD/X58mfC5@9DjUUu0E6gdf/Su1//RWjg/4Kxd9/@ER5Yg9@a/x9pKsX5EX/7/4BDu1lmDMmAC36/9u7b30US/Q9AIvgP6fWd8GUphL98Z/ECZP3NFYl@6Sdf/vPfobeYUanTqg2O3SWtlNoC/WarXPbHb39BB5L84jK0EICf03eQQy2FfQd527sffvPd7/zjdz/8jXc//GUcvKVcOb2bltQ7VsMgYv494mHEwvvEw4hfYP4pmmKTUl/AG/vCD/ziiy@E9qWCJyPvX4LvF@TFL8aD8OSkHxSEoT8epWSXLOr2nRnfuen7hjkz1nj5soXrreCHuadI9tgKRKN8ls1SPmIzxpd10B8izbbIOcM7@WLwTMDb4n/hnAksNfOne@GZWjjJ4afzs@BOIQ/ZpGbhYhLJaoxLR1vch9aJKd9cmWEJZrPUDJRgcEAOKQh6AOJ4rZbChDWOD7xy1OolRqikUjUoN6bmadLtEoKYPSAokLKWOmLtrdqMJ0whvHpAjpSAXkeiqompUu0hZFibPWQIC4ET2Jcva/VSbVZHcG85PVKz1APCCYHVUrP6W3ivEUxIJ8QevgVUSrVUql7CDLGQvHrSbV5JeSoclT3FUn4dwBO3@@/cZ@wjUS2JfJFgAwnGY@M9tYiNESE6hDdTW35x6D9w0m@LCL5BWfm5MB6@Q7LpDhdXMQLAlSRZlhn8cP19h92H4BkHlaJs4ZHiEFLUIqgFhB4M54dSQorqN0UvkH@stvXBFwLDwmxubgqxupgVD2UinaIw97RCZx9wOyCqFxUmFsoieht0ECTABdJXKf/NOC6sxRkHzD5K8d/9@1vsIygmPRd@ApNSWSfnxDiU7VRK1AB@3UkJL0AtEaCdEqBLQZ7VaCEvJaTTjMm1GIaxw8NDHwnyeFETUtDMtayK77icNJ1OY5BCltNyOu0/ZXqSh@w7ZAr1n/ImEpc@F840LVcF7anK0ItFVR0VVGD0fPv2LdQK7a@qHIDyyfytVlquRIHgwQ3EWNY8ODCk5coC18yZWsgxlqApVriSLCmwBNtKCnxXPkciuBJxrVSKUzygvpzYCnbeFVRqDji9GqsjosHFVcJSPhkE7h2yvcOnT/c/PRm3Wkww6PPnRnvsOl3D8xIYtvvpQ34iQysXkrFGA0GfVDRkMMJ@JUPM@ODh0cFxhfFC@1WQIMSqtK7qF7OsCrHx@PPtmL/zSMQv@DniMd4ri7IltHIWksbqQqxroGaBC@aoAFdZVXjqDR44M9Dp06KYVguo2SVpUpkJP@9MGdqX5cZooE/hOQ15e5soINQvJFq6QCfUVkGo1/09e0wV6sf7J5Dg5JCpWkYW6l@wmYwZSldC3apZhj2YDDdx85vYzIiRMm02Mmn807JZuKu5QlrNF1sbG9aFhHk2qdoucBfjFbxeSFiMr8LFhK8K7KvgBRfkgVsTmb8v9OCw6m/OQ0tuCb5DT1Tz0M2SAs5jc3DCOHpVoXUvLwQJsY1vfGPC6nXQr6WDR0IMuMWQBfvTJLMnD2Wq5t7UNSh0wFjP/MzETzPKPdMbW/ocug5QI3Z1ddUHSAePmFbX6JWn6OH9qks@HXBfzXQhZlcqtbdqrihop5XK26ymCeAhbCm4AW4DGgDtI9hS@F/Vg0yy2ZICnEoVRXhks1kB544FoWIIjPaKvM3UahJvg9mcSltFBPzahz6raeHlx519tIibzfC4GAIBbDBxWSYIK/Iw/60g0BsQDXfH0belq37nzNy7l8VJjGwuE85WUInZFdTNZjaXRYoL//@FB7D4as72uJ7NqNvKGJw6OHPbig7ODjjz20oHnCY4y9uKCc5pPatmtpVpXWDCNrflytBUTE2cGDM0Hc39xLpnWH0ZzxbVRMpAE7d92@j1IGG9V@s5XfowfLUnm7ZtuHiwmyfI5cSqY6OVwRraG6Gj8CyRvBAGtXM6fi4YtYGMhmtcW7eEntxxenPZm8wtPKVjOW4tDuJgPAhYQDdADsG5r51sNldpsJY8dsY7gpYvphpqBgYQ/KmltJbeMHaKxUpP7lqG7u7kK/lSuocHgPwlrp18pjKQv3j65PFkMj4y6FTQTq4MCdDUGxpl2ilV8vlWoyGKqQZl08LPWnP2JG1sQJ829J4ET1wA8ySt1ILEPdOt1eLxnayqSWolmyldCQvCIc2xhHUBk6awZGmk@4XPASq2YwOzqaT1tHlBVKj0@/2rrYvU4kXQLyT@BvS5kvR05yJ8rUqReBU2TUvmIhB89D6Q@8Jf26uIWr4kVhvVxXuxIFZbV8L9kdEzdTwM1Mxc3ExVAKbMocYgoyYTriqu40wqHaPvuMYiYlYtBBE5Qjcj5MSrMLtmBnO8uJldIRJpdnETSi4vXoWpArSEqyugOyc2kN031FunTbMNtZxr7QMLguazHdjwxWixFy@E2NbRZ9l6Har6IlfUcvlcXssWCvmiBuNNOVfIl6CzZQqZvKYBlFy5VC5eQbtWlLcx@kQf27sI2nuFPlKQ0CvcymajxZJvPzWti1JW4ngkktWrq9hbIfbR0WcaDJBrrwQMup9pUr2WzZfBlUWXlgWEmaBpkpaVsqqkZvH/DoeG/@8fX4N/De@QKqsJJ2h651MYNmGot9kTNOExcdiJgx9xGrAHRndNjL2hTjua91zH8/4ecR7o9ikPemhye7dh0GMdv2TnjczJcE2M5@MRWu0x3H8wCPujDiCI7JBHeAA313KcVRGK7PmzNaV8GlqYB2JwE/MQ/ejg48cnkefJ/u7eY6HAHhx@@vDaI@9HyrMn@49OwtciDw2S5kMQP7//5Mn1V/@RO3x@1J86Lv6ER4fPc4tb6IUHZoUcXMuRQm8C4t/wlQRLkChAEcsXA4cq4DGLe6Ac3/Od@cLCmUHn5/w0sOmF2/75wfCKcBIcEdYZctqOwbrcOBNq62Q40Zfl1WJZEMbMds5ZMcN6jmXpLnP6/Q3wHOp43NFAgdaysCVi1ueOa/XOzZ6xITzFk5VlFT@BjkgIjwHIaNoloxsgzKAZXhjVbIbLUh1rarDpmK31hAd6odM1B0MYg8@dIILQ0XUGvw@9IL0RvSa3e0x4HuR3I8S6GV0Ana6UF8U9UXysT/R61TVeVL1MpXLvnvrMFcviGAZl3RsY@zNot@w59CPdnafFiSw@Yu0BrmxYzhh1EG/cAKG9rDVaOzmtXsrks6W//s0f/d2f/NqgpjYzexlpe@fpk3wFmBvIsYxEVV@clUmx0cqlfKmc1UrpUrmUy6uFfD6tamnQCYtlUAsyakktlPJlNV3KlUEOyZUhNF8u@sKwEki/ylYFwNpd/Cj3NulG8hCUIL4Qyd4k9CSL6eH7lIkGpBEFVEMndHh8y6zBEMrUDMsWGUDUWZfFHj3ayzx6JIoP8AU3cuxlRLGHL/lSJlN8IIoGheyVUKYSHZ6mhOYNxQl/yWQeAJGnHAB@GUAUh/iyX8AJNVE08WVv99EjzKePLxqmh2inPIS/WMFLEaLZ@AIyOgF4HUKDaLs8nxwhuo8vmCWGPOIhexAmih8H6GDIEY/GATwOSrq7K4oH/GV3F0P2qNh5jujX8GWXLlF04QUavygOwDFwoduJYgec2AVEsQuu7lwHP/wAOhqPtye6KM45eZBAojij2Hr3VBTbgT9m85mPTR6pW6EXlZf6Pr2U8U8UtQBpjJYNX7KimAtfclC2x48/04eTnjHg19zlzy6U9PHjrG7OpvuPOh9/3BkMOu58d//jIwza23sM8sh86nYGHT9hpw2XA6n2Hmv66Wh@/YJSH7TbFd1aGfS1djun29eC2vO2gRhCqteAmX8NMKNRew@C9h637@urFpIJYBt7/wieHbwejOD5QO/woOCiIHrOOh2xis1fUZoJATUGXALG7ngK3NROj/Su61TxfVZjmTQKLfNGIdOqUgAbgeSfqV5heD@Bdx1nf5IX88aslmnVZrWixnci9RNic6blTTG9MdpRy/nKhr6jarnUrIL2K5x@nMUldYcl1Htbb1ji0@SOBlqA2NzZkcSG2trR1FKlUHyxNRXFZAXvO9li5U0iE88whrdko9jaKeYjKYrFlK5olWIRZDGgyQSG9A5OyrQTiXNDP00mEVuaIoAiUFnZnMppVvuJWXpW43ixebI6q6lVbjSZZW4A66GF/ml34rgc5ADAzXYyFVyDT4hquSQCAoqSSCZDpgcau7DYBPr5109OT06@IKGv7s9ePHMN5F5V//Xjx3vywWHwhrb15UcoizquvIdcaymEC6WB1wloIfJjGEZBowv88Jyg61jyPu2dA4E2CAjM@8i@nVv55PESnOOhc85zRjMLVTKWaHcNhp8eMHtMr9XBpfdYgrBievKcBvB2vV5r10ZkiQCKGKT6GiO7/AswBx7HPTT@QMkv8OycH9CuZa6qndosNgM47RqT1Jcjp/dSS3WrPfziwIPaA0xcbcOzUzVqhus6rgj6tFjt79i1qe3pfeOZ4aJZk4PDTRAn8EBdos@M5CZr7mPsPdRVrqS6y@wFZp9ORwldqneSy144Mxd6IHESXw8KfUFnPHGXxlW1X2OJFxD1Nby7myzRkx8kd3JVoNMD1k6CV@Zl/2WfaayQq5KukUBY0JWIPlhunSVr9a/Bg8M@rVQAG7@iTwEqZgaAzR4FQOyxeVXt1iyWkNiMJYlIueqg1sDkl3jblkSxJUmNy5ZQl6TPhTr01@o8pte8aYc@VsMyHVXLFKoz8FOLueoQqld/Mau6tfHUNaoWvPoTevw4q14FogLtAMyby8S7X/xmclvK17hflUBdWiB6tOV2bVa10fwlNIxatgYBqUYukwYtHm7FNIz5WiGtFtLZdC4tFdEXBvx0Pg2eoOWAgJGwEiJjYjozy8hqWjXUdCLz0uy9TKZPEyC2ENFYMj1x9u3piIEPVBW2TXqFJ5AnpW1ZoH31HKZvS9RYgWVUsWBA9SEbm@khgjoydItSJJMSy24lrM0Extk8mY73G61KZX82/joEJaTXO4VUMZN6k0xWExvJmme8FupVoY7shUo93oCW6891Mm86akAtg0stapVGo4NFLGbS2UwWSme2LwfbYl1spTMbBRWq6IoR22Ccb0Sn/1DiWfiN2yh9WwZUnVrWqoJMc3HZkiaVlfxWPsPnA3lKYeyzN6QkSzTF4Oh2Ih4vavF4Ml7FlYgN0Z96Bp5G/CwO3DV@T90RQRgTK2JZwwgL1kinczMBdiCOXQkoFbIcKLcXwtXF1XZd@IpwjGcut7UX@Fd88XT3EP@@Al5leC29ePr88PnhI4EptNlTbseqG1W52q7CiyTX7wuxCmPASZu@XSllg7EP3Uaa2q6/4M8mnh8AuAKZtG6wFm3vMkzU3NhnaLNgh8WhDLo7amhattXQijD2ATcNomqaWsV1mhieUJDrUBneBeC3narjcb@vsflcT0mBun@PsUFqUyDyxK7PBezWdgdHu8EOtd291TMGm2MFJ6lXB9ZBHjo9Vf1zO8VMW6zGWFvM@wfkFmd7cuK2n0LMFbMU2BREEffIxS7isfgV/MXiAdgXb4KTQAWxepopby@dEyoH54SKWlt8wbzqKRrp3BZi9@k0pMZPQ7JYeB4SF3v9dZpsrsCS5WAZ5Svx@7F4PI7rFRXmvY3FVpXwtCrGs@l4MR1X0@x@vFjg6FffiLmwmD5mJcCn@oIwpjYZHFX72ksNukPMdgIP0Ahxtg6G63we1wdiysux9w2tlH16cGg/dB9Fjk29qMfwO@USngCrVl60N05V6AZZMXuajrH7MTo1IJYBE417QAWcMhWwgIpg4vOHh0/FHNKrosbBKwFU4/hDps2Nyw0HF4RYuE3xrf3J1xkbx7M5qIxmLTar5fz972q9LqnbGtqnK7IKDHp9tSBlLuu8W9cpoKBByLtf/EFutl2Cdy2jwrum5VNava5uaSwZG7/78vfR1NDF/me7T1gclxH@7k9@Ryv@3Z/8K9ppF7@ipQUtW4xBTHSqhWLs4mJ8cXEFFw/Lx1oxjlSumAQ3X@ZSY3VF1bK2bVdZRdH1rWIqp923q4ofVy2qyZgnxfzNpdlCXkokVAWw2sqWMkkIu/RjapkSvAULbDy6WICKggLsH5l5Tb2/vQPl28nmtOoGNDk1PIDLwr9twyujovv05SVj8NKt9wYDUyOXorDKW4ltv5W22Vtc3norbbCXtTpuk1Dx2G6w/LOFxxhxCTReTylbcQZKIqs3rqpXrRStH4E6/cIwtuzmtVbb3MBzLMteWzb8GVse/WGiwMOD1@DN2HrliYmtpKL0euLN3rBtsHwdGsyWsjhczLaCVSH@J0nN5Ltf/HVNK/zdn/zqZfuy/YUGina5XFC12E9/uj21p57Rq/8UANxiZiZQlkleRnsw6AiVbMbNgpp@qtAhd0G/n9qoUPD4gcqNSjYDYcwc2EaPVG7hDAVIqtw2t3TYS1C0LbRCkSaFhCyLJauCEEjuXOFwB900wWBbaMu20UoKF8JXMQjkEwZKS1X46gIUeIxAInG6bc@aumM6B5SgdGorze5BEsjhq2hEcoOsZ/iDmwRcXtm6mZSj7BHVSNhkI8Pz0CQljMvCVyGJb/DbmrOxjoZeMKZpw2gqYxTCkwJ6Dci7BXlbPEGbfBNUeh4hzTh2PJENSonwVZCviAomiF3M3IYIVeBfXwUCQBkSPmCzxbZZNskuzFSqurB3eYUnFtAipx4YmRAwGULroVGTIHEV44EXKEP4iVlsF34Ng9Qb8QyAcBh8g0MN1ClMTm8oyZIVmPcGBbDI4lqCisbu3VtgVauZvSSjEiH8U3OM04FUD/ZqXAFYoIp@1KuIaYaWRKuBb9jsgOIpQhdancRNiFYjSZmIr1eCAP/v3WixRV6rKgqoYgH8@uK9ogskg8RIdl6HXbZdY6pWTLIQ@S7g3iWk6Kh/qF83Zx/J2hdB4BVg@NNY8AEnYFon0SlWv91etzLCQPuY4tdz0NYcZwa@dRBuTQ6Z38EkSB2mgqKYFsXumy5ofrTzIjBkmciqSUy2MPxJeBAf13IMt/bnk/igVBibwVNHg4x@PhtkSKrrQIV6Y8cmC45kYQrPVUCLAB7lG7/jaE/tc/zaml83lDiKkUeG77DlI8ZkkZI@U09pcetDxzX004A2aWYMZNYd9ZhWZglqaGSkzw7BJSkRIdwBBQJp3LGMEaB0bBh0GM@rKMoAhMpphywVPjWhXQ0fmTAC2Z7ykBNYOTdPTeUEzR5LTh/P7HG7LzGUQ7H78V0WvlVAy3FOmWWeGnzmPLFkNcdjoEKBFpAGyi5@QNgKbt/RsmmcyQHxiWLBrwiPIneW0pG0G4l58uYzq24k2lijlzTemFArlnGm2xH60nUp@HMH3twL7G6R9Sh4l0OWa/gWd2pxtKURmpISfAtiNTJeJeOKzDghxsTA8hY6hbFrnDGcBRBwjAGm2Q1s2GAvhtJ@lQYA6nvQs9Ag58StoOUlwMTtJbrQ9XwGb7OPWFYTMCI3i@abMAMYWPW1ZegQBkmxHN6kBxUj0zIE8hXonaMehKHND7/5YfqgdaObjKUumjfb8MHhoEN51RjvFsFLPvKCvQPbMxV9AwILgOEKTDYSYgrApsSkyEGH6a8n561dIF5SYTchpRlC8EkNUEhU0JHloMXFyGfRBAh4oHv82xm@uc7z83OZbMhOXVM2PPxUmOfYuqWMByaI3o4yMUZj/6PMZlcZB3AXLol/IVAeD8c7M5Rua@V7c/4UhL5X8zdBJeJ9L46D4xl@CWswIntzaOjNowb1yKSv6HUT/p4s3v60VvoiaH8VbH9SKX6FQBhDMLP0PN1NA7B0p3ua7p/3qn7AGXVIAA61aASeaNnZDV5GXuAyx/0whjNBPhoGdaxTWtcGSCKf8l5kzUsYxJwHr/772JxBIts4Z7uuq88TFJ7E2NiAE3MSe9gchn0KASfaFb/gZobNWWPeWko@C5PDoBbu6nDRmJxwcTtQbnMaw2c8fAbhMx4@W2QaZNuYtbhIhl5XWBxs9WiDNIiJYOZBnCtun3kRQpBBHgeVivww5nzJ7wp@3RqlDujN36Aea0HDgDYxBoIbCaXxotlotmzPON9qpZQBNHaRCAE1DqAbLaLpeS90I/WtM2vseEteNpqehVHJxxu9ukO/NfC2gmUMK4gaBqeXidZCByN/@wkXCPwCAwSUwyAQRYPdScJMVkMb5xQIDachLmjMEWv4yLRI@vKDfD8QlzjpOWGjgFoRQOgfFgnQhBAW9Bz@YciAO3zuOhAniCvRt@xGaLUu3ooDJa91Fc5rqlRJEawkKUATyI7iau16UYJwqIrGtaBIMa/8@o@iv/HB6PehX6zGnhosHzCqQrSr4I5PECH87kJUZfVapF4BA2VLtwwXRq59Lp/6ozVks6UEagbPB4vgnZuT7jARqfxuktcPnSsVbbESNoV5rQZFnNd4t@T9IiApJ3iYzPOTzYOG4KfnDARgZFYmM/xks2iyWa3GGQebrUl2HkFyRkjOeBIee7YGyZafDLSng2B4weppgXSKW1JFgKfyYRTEoLHIPP3MwE0Cr9CiJi6z@HkueA61Ar8NoYiN7azbWpl7I4J0hGldA4AN8QaAHv/GdEW4zvBUKXwLeRQnZcCj@JvfDDivgAZGLLjKrU4nwkZGOjAI/GKKxgHou2KqIYgqTZXjX4b/xHTgGfzUm56Z5Zjqsmcmfe3vH8SzhZSNdNCI9KFmcsiQUZN5bvvmWqMyR4ztTkHBAamuc@6wxAphG/yVqZ9U6VhORxnpuNkHvzzLfeXxPBnoD7jYxO6PnYk@cXK5CleaTGp2q/LnOoM5sB38YFXE8jzIej3H8Oz4BCq16wxs0zPSDI2Cnhq@2mH4n8IQonKy73Q8QfC3nXE1FkHzdoWibrtt2uak3U7gbs5kJdyaTps7sXnG4wLqv@CKpAf25AM9HCecziujO0neDRM/o@AnOzG7p4nDsR@IU7W7DHhYF@R/CB2CBMM8Z6E5kol2FKU7kwR9/mPojJwBSH1TTxYw9TXwBwvYiJA@HhMuaaajSluJfEyDekmim9aTftKvfXBS9jUtoSfD9NoygCVipJl7ncZIWXdFdu212fFkQX7HH47vcRTf49vxJS38Os5cNa/xwA/LOptYQICICzSyd6OBRQe@1buBzhIqoTfKVTzBe6PYo810PcR0F6Lu@tHlPrSPdPjmwVuI@Gfr6H97BQbJ99@3@nTo9ux4DvxmhPtSE/SNQS9YM05A9IMk8p6b2YVN@@F75gVx8fOuj1CEADGWGJeN1qWhY45B7fbCCeQA8B1tHvev3Wj3tKmtxgNX4OSepdmptr6KHrZ7hqXPjV7Cj5mOwA1KfAQKG/Gr9ys4Mjpieg7X9RIwdiXDUBjGkeg8UmVNk9HTZ8nk@mbFo5hh66GZcsLwYD39MPwGa8YpvhqfrQY9IB6P4XTsmYnTn@P5eM4/YGDxD8z5fJSPP7wm0TbG3QQBOvDRU00vsk3exj6PEmGR/t/uvnatjWRJ8ze6irSEG5UplSRsMBYWtgBh6xwMHj7s9mJaXUglqLaQ1Crxobbdz8z82BvY@T@XsLcy9zC/9irOxhuRWZUlCYy7z@6ZZ85z2pSqMiMjIyMjIzPj4x4rQlzWS3cZ8cUNRIScmh7D7yPRt3tKg2tVqppRzqRT98we8fCuEbe4wvCkXEbdjyW/xXT35jmL1QRYIsI2v28JmYIMQ5dWK29DlDd3jli/NyUT8I7P6Xq3rCrNGQI1rsmSbhTydpv1CyeDnXGD/uLA6R39BcCzYNQUhjJ9w5mWztmq@MuFP7C0Fv2GlHSCYlFRSK7RsEplzDMV//w1brN1a5utqTZbqTbjGZBu0iqUaaWa1KOA4blrCLpBZ3SLdMYn7J3pz11im/7X6/tDnFZ8XggXKqGrFq4WKiSQF4KFSj1PQnmhvVDZ4odooXLAD58WKn@lh2RuLXxZqJhpgQJD@skPL/Fei3D8bi1UNvPO18zI/xREpl1voRKPKZV5IT@ZIkQK9Ju0Rlyx9fq6m6NhQAsbK5WuAsdELrZPfA7j8n8l@r8k4@I0PfiIM85HXFgtqnJq0bBWDGmHlg2TBmLGTK7o1by@t82GYnERNLNIezy7DoMnNTy3kBZGghi@8o0G/SUEITcrszFS1kp2T3R068ShPMjp9pl6HusD7Tx/P6bCJ0kjnIFN1zfjlQYhA3g/PFH5Njyn0DHNMUa4k3VmoAWi/rxwR6cw1mlc9OjbI8Rn3elChG3BFJFRYrCWTCcdji/n0NigP0gzCX@FS0Jo1@FDOZmU4N6JaiwV9My85TO/1j2DYLAnv3NXd6x6QC0lgvDxuHQisyxeF1gW41Mi6yxNVSYfoWDJHJrhQesTZ7fb0o9cTsSNy2vFbcuQqStNsuRKi0mq7CHW16U/ktbjzWsdEcC@b/tqat7grCUPAFbNuBWRr/3v0N/7or8bhdoQYaKBWYr17KV0Wr2@c5WdwLybNDs9gPjoqi1npnIUt5CQnHYHlmZ@F69Nqfgw@RAlXxqNoU9o@4Zs8Z7gG3Sb3FsILGgJw6v0y09L9PLT0u2EmtZIuleeUVo8tKThSMdjTJOu3Y2rdHzWEOMLn2/73e8e4GF6gO3BAzzuwHCC5DLLh5c9tnJJ5jaJbXkDkVquKBHkfF0aD3PyksQ9X93G17b0Yq@5v7W3u/OBFt2nT586eo0eJ/hh1uKsNV7HBTJbncfrwYxty5KLFFS47MZxfHTeH44efOxlp2SJCGtSBnxqxbCfnuOOlmWWPJ@Yu1RPyloU1bA@JdPAT0klqDo@luxQ03VEBAlG@Ue@BmLUW6K3y7s1h5MtNZs9/yJoNnn5Mvmm9SqGoTE34s7fcg@Kl9GQ8ypLprDrTIaDbqitPfX@de1QHb6uq@2jzb@qD3tH6n1t9xDxFt4ebew0NhX9V989qKtMynQSWRWxoSS6bgWtAKly1VKp9EQx5M3@YCxyJ7/pyPsD/0K97rcCXFM9j/yLl@fyw@sFo3WpVaft6BhnmCFn0bwIR7C34LSPtI2FctNmN0q4SSgqe0p72gvseS/67bATUtkM9r6DMIiM553qhjSCJG@N87krShIyPLLpEGduhQXWNVX3qTzubgiML/ZXIDFKSErItqc04eL/fTcFD@v7bw4UQnds7u1uNQ4be7sHantvn36@/dDYfUX0bBwc7jc2jvCJC77Z22psNzZr/EIQKHkKMTV@uYxGd6LgoThTpfUJN9/egIY//pU@9YYGr659diiN1MJlD9In9Lvhb0F7YS1zGUF9gRMrXxWo/Hxt/9U7WvNV8CtuOM1VMNsfZI8izjo6X1LPuTWaLOs039b0dKVlr1B2@D7iYqyQeChY41gbeX52lQHORjztMFDZTdio4OxbQnLwXDagqaEHBBugjMFKVXHCsIUF9zmDXKfWWt0@4qdKa2JEqH@g6ktjarKWYYppWxkAhSNIo4fzoPJa/IL4nl4s6WZHQymgHscvpIB6Ii@gijZgO6KWdYnL0d4lxLNakRe/XAy2@VpYPY1fbPi8i13VOMm48ZD6Kk64iAAlXU4LJ6c8nLqWk9FzlYjLI2VatysTI5BknSQT5SqRbduoZJaETQdXDdrsTXJg4ytxA@yE/M4oUvmq46lDGAcFvVAS8p11/Z6YQCWmO8x7ahWxoKraXz2ME9mxa82gzwyIJJppPOJ6W1orDO5bj2puTLXoaxtJTiZrTNC@hcDGFAJ/BAwBKqR2Oi1eqdjHF2D6Hc3K@ahPHIlz29/t8sTO7ctWkKqgrbbyv4S//eZoIrupfZKxU2TsaIh@C4akVvJVZqc/pDnOYpVTf0EKts77g1EoY5hP94BvnHiZo9JY2Ki1n6vrqdZAh8kWe/2e1egpcfEtrZ4SU96nVeZ4uTuPxVeSE5o4nxZhsbsDOv5p/yqw7s5cXCJdBzh@IUWY78px@DkeMSaif2YS2fG7QirZ1er61sbHwu8/u8gnK2JB0jkbo0P8R4yJtmh68D0fGywOoXfpmWbyAEaXp6itbfC0tMQsN8BoH3ge0r7uZXMt/ibmxtPv4XY0@Z5ffvlSlVoFSCadAzw6zyfSzVXHpkmX65wobQJiyU5ClmR93rxxGWYsr1/C1QijgOBGPcgR7NsnsuxpEWJ6d3rZIcmikx3r4Y7hO2qdLSqSTPFwIbLHo/hTfqO6uO4UE4MSZZEzb0S0ayCXHccyS@H1agrc1t3gSH7fH9zqndjJ8vBd0LbuhPZduBUWb4cly5IF6/5gf78DrCxufwgs9d29HbAsktPQYk6PmdOdz8XWtHe3@PPU2PHcIzBYe3GCEgO1Wrvs8RW1iUaelwqODSZRiA4Ot@r7@yor@xOqS3IPW4a2FoOA/UC9Taxtwx4LOy9WmuLNcqw8mTcpi7bEqev2yTyTeLeICq2DuJoesbBIYp53whuRenplYRWCre9ZIBrKpbH7bGRQdKwBf6U9ICGbDJrVwczMbuZk8Qkj2whc080V3di24WcLa1m7kUJ4OLYB2TZB/hk8S2aP33vRjyumHVGwEBEKHW6TJk3rDe0TDqjhARX0vPQI3jEsZkhhZC8Kds7QDoZfpbSG/ecZihlJlHDRhS2xrpVjjZrox/NGzWGDRCwDPiw99UexaKYPRsTzm@f2gDrJopdPL0GkZCKp7EubK6j6yVe9hDE14nWyGivk9lybZ2yODZYnOJ3VsNduL/QQttArk@JhsimStnc2Vfj7NCWrRKolQ/OZnTEfCfLK8vLjb8Ge7IWpXvizsGUNmZSfo4sB7e8TkNE44uN94tzGrmu@JwxwB@nEtN5MmImKpOrMWFNSfefFyMaPcJFzIUIGIfyRp3eyVUfdTOA2G7qsSDZ0LjLVB2sKxx2VWTNF/a93NweB/M32Hnx/ezLZUAimg19hlf@mP4yCxCvPin1jvULMgPS7YDjscTHxZ7oAlDy7Md3pbMfedmLwKr3CR75vs3vS0d5JYnbrmrMGboSPFz2k5sbp3trk8V6hvGZ3dbuxU1ePOKRnJ3UWmR1mHUv2PAh7dyHAMpjPJbB8sA/fw6hC/xEOrgFJZGJvvjzTxvkmbkwR0pqPOceTNgvVsrU8OfqdqOX3EC3FzT6MVNb9gSryKWx9b9uZdbJeWkvVJ@SiQS9PtdxswctyVXqHA11ASoOQ0cR7a8GCp4axlIR7zVkf9lG42Apu5PSMLSf9Ynm1tPIsw73ruSP34vjZifuoVc0qWnz93kV0Obxufzrrn191VFcNfjm9aY1/@1Wp5SfqMbW19IPEVS6vVIscyvYp/buqnpWYczWCLzhGNFJFe5JDV6kFlezD1x4ohx9401yBh8QEl6pHF4YL4WI3ql4cr5xUe9XS2sVx72QNTn6jxeposbyYx4sfaBUlGSM388ejE6yp9qlr0LtSiF7KuVq1a4hi1xB688Yfhv2d2u6r1GkcFAAcgWlbbz5Ql7Tcc7Bmg@@J1wuu8/qYzFXg2AwUpMwcewWVERKAz5NxHNMOCTMaFZe02eiG/x07mbmSdzkY9fmLiVUJ1lJfwi@ZOePGVOITBSpyHJqIlvAvIDhJmTwuhuTtWKyoC2VR18rwnXQsEMeoyeIw@zGbhU8hENW@XMcnmcgL/NY5kEAe@i9cTT1/zlnpidUij0/xYMrhD9lhonSCR1yA0J8B3zagCdbcI3b7yFD38buMB3nDZ1Qj9pNhA/kMa4r4AvNv9Zn9m7j@cyKAEH5OdC5PH3FqzYsUSfEd5MMFBIJLb/xxzQC3ShmUOXQWsKW9agKcLcWZRmhWk4nez12DnEIr@p/uQaHMv6a6EZd3pDiThO@p9a8ItOQh5U/r@NNNquWtagVTzRS2SDH3TWrgpIu2R28CmlZjtRl0u4S00GIuIQce2b9Xt78Ytx8do82TGHn5Xpj6Xkh99@S7IJWU8miBTwpV7ELZ3Oek3FeVTYq5U21VFSsvHo10yyOVJCm7dlfZyBv1m2FSeD0eSuHK@MPz1IeC9eWnGaMvXx6k6sQMHn8/lu@av5f0yMdYpsq@TLePvxk9QAEbz2pbkwku9Xph90VGpzDXX8BmWaKmUlKdU1MqM6mq2gdTixPS4HDOz9N2vZpAWSwbicNzJrv@/GXW00rGi/wkGuLFODWxZswRi0rc5iIT7oYdFqkd/vzAAsEwwWjKzNx1U3msK48tsCj1wDQrXpBTE5y6NjnFq/CL/IJ/zGRPI2fK5WZ/nBPMb6Tz4t2cJhAL3QfZ2WRKSxO4i8hL3ak7VpGk7fEkxNlCYtc6BY7bDMQHu4Nj8AexnLAFhZEUU3SPv2hKJwXKhn1vG0J8/Jr5W/FR5pVPOvagG9yoGrYZPnthZVIO7qMgGkWIl8WhfKLLwaCLW0dW@K7ZhVqnClhaxnVLAtFa2b1MA5Y9Ut7Fk3ZIp0qe2gPkaxiIJB@iy7MzOJPBA7Z/DdGKE5dw5GVqvbEcaNCcebwkbuaBQvANFsDd8MxGQkZOZg8oHQ38VuBlSEeLSPvJSFc7oU7oyufp8BtBWDZa0iqZzD9dhq1Pm69wn/u0XHpctkh2pa@DS97jJ4mDFRHJfFhCZMXl8pNMxrobbsndcAEAXbWDhf4d8WZwFfR6QaZGKwYXjEhpjYLhVdD2Mpn9IL4EBlywMm4m4Yfdvxy25HCHlC6fmBFewpEr12HEYfiL9Vmui1t8V@ZmcGmV3DbTUF@FbRDQeJx0@rgd5gsLhAkQeqDSRTAiojxyVBolvnvWuLDucoGDKKIG4pxYdxMxGXr9UdiikeGTrEyXQMk1SNJYrz2BCbXX6vpwDvZmIQD3mIQCBgFzlXQXDhl9af5dOCjdMXPH7puRKZL06/NcoekeDEOSvgmBeVS4moU7DfDh68aBOtjbPnxf268ren67v/eusVXfUhsf@I4bF@UcpVi93tsh6RLfpsut@R69yNYOqGaWP2Rqux9U/ce3@/WDA7W3rxpv3u40CBqB36/tHjbqB65q7G7uHG3x7TtBULt7h2qn8aZxSMUO91xu1VTLJPXU3rZ6U9/ffE0/axuNncbhB25xu3G4i8Zwq19Tb2v7h43No53avnp7tP9276Cu0LHMVuNgc6fWeFPf8qh9alPV39V3D9XB69rOzkRH997v1vcVGwlYvdyoE5a1DdrCoiXu51Zjv755iA4lT5tEPEJwx1UHb@ubDTzUf6xTd2r7H1wN9KD@T0dUiD6qrdqb2ivqXCb/DarQuGwe7dcRQQmUODjaODhsHB4d1tWrvb0tpvVBff9dY7N@sKYyO3sHTLCjg7qrkG6SmyYYRC36Ts8bRwcNpltj95DWjKO3sHdwaJDfE2EIyxpV3WICwwwCvSUi7e1/AFTQgQfAVe9f1@n9PmjK1KqBCrCo2Dy0i1GDRMRDu5tqt/5qp/GqvrtZx@c9gHnfOKg7NGCNAxRowCDjA7EONXrEvcY4EV7ySMyaMZzr8nCqxraqbb1rAHNdmjjgoKG5hcm2@VrT3EMMY@sQJezjzMC/sA9WOtOvrgJE7Zw@kZl9RhNHTNrc26rTiqyDXWWTD0e06qxOhFKyv9FKE3@kn6mQNe3g9PKsGfY6ffiYxtXk4OMiOnORRMlBBpqPmTtyienzFa6QyzWb72pN2ugeNJuOe5@aKTS@VUMfg99VytF9RIYK7Lxx8FOpCN2fpwi1/oO@6GRDPVxAoKRQ/wcxffMvAkcVi@1AV4PzPgCbo6NIrk3OcZVCopGdHZE6J2mSTyb4d6jZgSvmDXiv1cQ5KSwjuVA/on96X5IfsjhYL0g6y3FXsYhNLKMR/haYZqQRDonA/@iIBGGHm/SiIPh0li/ZzWHP7531@@2845g6XHZE@8CzvPON6qfB2UT1wmR9RpavnXVyh8jsu1mFie@fNcmUHhdvyD3L45/miP84BhuJ@YBTU26KD6v1oWX@B6kOiyRX6dAWcK/gQYbO96b2Y@M9dnOlpSdrE@9fx@9lbsFeEPF9acE75non/Of1iRSgCcaxOIgkoY6QUSxadYy9SVz4mgqeo9B12IblD63V5wGv60QSUmQv/a7dJlbjYXhjY09y@NV@7c3G0fY2iU5g@2R1@enKWiYOu/WjK38/oB0OwctRxwa0jpOexp@sWbJJig/PFCsCesL@zMDFIgoiur0ZNH6JOA@x3UbakgmCDN2NkEeqBxO9bAA6ZBUH4HiQMfw6c2ZqBsinuuqgNxf@Dav4PulKzAPamKU75lG7wT@AHU9/M8XjDmkG0izGQYmJc2l3wXIvu21MRXlzw4F7UMTLGj6WMG4xDfioi@1n4V3LvzRvW6MYiSkj5isPO9ckJB5MYqGMXUVPZvZbjjOiD4A5ehi9@VHzGz1@0AHuONydH41qowMi43ZcE@fUyWG07vSxhnyCbCMIqmZaeq5wyu9opHju6ePkODCINRsYFaTOgY1vGvBaHEdkskm2gH254KjPwqkI3gE4a5pj9W/i3Fnd0VDWTPwQ/dtEpVACKw5yIlS7jtvImCIf4jgWhpwpMv0pejD8fyBNZsB/TjtOgp5QywoCeC9KMlShFW1fmSjhtblosG43Emrarz4kYL7aA3Med0zf3tyIfw2RQI/O2Lz4wGEPO/kZBACT42DDnr@xSdq5T1unl1lHV8c9Sa91McgrvVaYpWIKbmHlxGW1yzV3K/jhKEfOmqwGd6iqeikbt1Oe9bRlmtjKq4dRVsA5Jv5H8REfgMQTnrn0XKxWJzmrpGeZkQM61JK14LTjiEmkln699dbukbJCZKZkv775MoQi0OvAZ7qfnHalr8Q8Nx1xkVdidchR8BBoHdtkLD46ZN0pG2J2A8B52ObDEGRmGV1jgegKdA7Vl0BT@YdsKIJGEqvDJM4gxK3jEWl5Wb2OseeTSXBojP1RT2L8B3KqZUp4EuBDY2i7y3vqjT8mlLv367awWPHRQd@F7SIak2MJXR9ZaFr9/pBURx/9JhzdcOx46r0@dAh60eVQxy@k9Swc6hMJo/RTM1CbZPfOy4wE12fUonAEb4W2x/zBXboIYCEq4UluCisqT8xreHTdHDqGN4tllX@efHlONOGwpEzE52pFffkipYSgOmRowBQMo3hzwTab3A7uHeLpd90ffsLaDxWo1w7acWRSCySfBcogNXoc47E1kq4P@hGfaNBQ4AQkpkRZDtJiQ1Vao59qdtJ2TdkkOiZil3JPvr@dmEmNtRQ1lDCubp2Yb6VAgwkqLenQoHGw0PLSMqMya8P19dbNGEcLTV9bq@zHXixSKqJEVB8a1RFPIjfjpw940of81YcRZg@9wR23VkGBMHRW3KtOyznGDzYF78Ng2LbPREmTafsDHL/x1qffY140R4c67F/LH0XBmHYArWJ4U2QYzfxf@ue95ma/65@F/dCnfRoi49@IxMPjmB8xYGfD/nXECZb4Q9sq1B4nzxJfRsKw4Xd8L7lmheaKRsEgb5spjIbj2rmEieCTcxgBJsldmb8HkzHS4jpPlpNKmbT/KdvjlZ21W@s@Ls@qLDf6AKAF3PqEBYX4kI7YMclyPl2bKnB6VwELx1NVUL5zi8VeCuNnRCK@hklhbJCZMkuwO4Gd2a0YH7dv3DbHIBwi0FKwFSBVUJTn166PfNkkRV7AUqCiyqslq6rcotwgDiEexreTe@npPxh7QuBPoF9@PItbZjECi7iOibYUyX5FRxklXNg8MGQZzZKYpFh4FvYs90POy3EzCTX9eXwbNdjyh5QiHWZviisxI/O08UEewHyTRE5z7GBRWVALDsftgApSG@VLtzNs8C37WZ78uMSVkzMIpk0NOW8hfRupWkQlZCSeMK@1UZaYyt@eMUtL9x21CQJWZ5mcWZmx81mjubAHSijrK661@kMSxtkJ6mlTj4Vo1B8s3JN6t8qOmZHZZtG65TjfNAQWZqvSYvmozaStjvE4XstM4jPBNGmKsaUZ8RC2r/wcs/kkEW@qTcy3anP8DTrcRrPEbipeVOLxbsvcx6J4BYtes9DEU4pxR5DStfj9cZM63rxdgmiYsr1qssRoQmQ0x/JogZogU0yl@1OIuU/jPkGPNlEO7baJdvb43ErUSSM5E/LUfEoFuQQ9EbgdTpsklwYdGF8gTJxouLGQihXOG3fMV3nlwimCDOODAIRWHBSScyg5wU0Ga4KPODtAJ9@EtVAZkoie1m0Lhzjof0wwjsqvD3e0xUNzXCifrAmkmxgS7Sq41F2QjL85/Txu3jCUKVLQFJ9BirhHU7Lp/P69@rN9oXIEQWrzZ23pW3LRGUctEjb0j/2peQMdOGlK10zNqPREaLJooLlAu5SzbiDbVWh/4VA4HtYNehrRBkJe5/FnUddAOO@VUkxtVLlpj1HE0eSW2eaowrpUSRhKfoP8eiqKqssbVwIQCMZUv1omCAhrytjjUoBD79icl0JUjxFVrJYxLeklR0VN7DxnfAdRdYEny1aJ0qwSz2wYhZlASLGYXSZBhHSW2UUSKLTQzcTFKvF0dn@SEqQQG94XitNQ6FFJ0zAeOSEgp@IuOYlEOS4rt6Q5mD8@WXZSH2P@5q/PStbX0uRXok@M4XGhPPl1tZT6mmp2aSldNVWT6OHYraY@EikcG@FYKvy5/7Frih3yPLYJtTYZKS1D22cjVTrtMmnf5v0SqefslG10DAPP9gw326@mpFhJBWW/OwC7WuArA8Ru/9O9NZapBhOdK4Dj0hlnl7xsCFljzWKpR7ew0zWR9uIABWZP2@@od4fb26mwr6djY2h0EQyXS6USmPjUDn5vbKtxlBT2i@nSxc5lt1scXP9l@O60yLI/CDglQMXsoAMaEpoUkdcfnklmCOBARVG6oB1Zsde/7HTsFAy4ocTg0bBJSR0NQfECFMZGL@8O@QCIQeoF9md0EP37WcWz79oXRVNDMddQVBsmwVdZc3tG5MGLDuyz45sqBgbBbKyZaN1yquufsYIgswkPFocvdj4n5snZ10G323fVe6RoRqSAua@TFba37QolKYIbRvbuvYw4Hq2rgquwa/kVo4jN6wBnFiaTZ8LEhUds/P3grH4zyGePf8rSskJdXkQ3FxGf2lXZs6yjg8XfA6zwIaF9r9IX/iDfYjpNFqalXs/g5Ikwelx2Z@59UkUcPhPTNPt2aRB1NroeB2ugrjusC5hY9jy83JNbisfEzX68KXdAw5LA0Dgh5sr9asDV7B8nFq9Gnc79pCKnAZCB/S6JKJlQ/pxA5DsAnoF6@hE9EUX7rwWa1tsTAUVEwUGyjmm5gwpNVMhkHraqv17na7Wamh8sLqpabYMeCgVV26ipLbzY2FBb9HsDv3@oLi0vr4nM3XI@08sN8/Kr2iAYfMK52DofbtFP@laF3xistTHE88XqvLs236w@X1@Lise1Dbj109N//sv//M9//V/Fmv7x7/ixwT@Of4oLeZ5XnG99nv/h6xp@H2@dLMyfHs8PThbO1sBlf@Oo4f3GqOAn5qPe8DSTk1XAest2pGafzdFndFVlkgde@MNPJF0qKteKijn9NpLMUSxjc63Aeh/Aj/KUtvAm6cDkVp6QyBHQMY7jaXRaAQzwaL0hShIusAOV@nK3Yg7uEQ4mLhDfquR0JB7WWa8C@LQkkRTgi0srViHsRUEPJ@BXrPNK9zIZn/6Go6bm3@JPb6Kzjf6NevQxrx6V1CNXPcpm@U955Rm9deaLIbxzpRhtB7JZl74kVwswM1RRyIoe7x84184EuTOZeU7ZA0gmTAUXFi84N979sbOMJFyLzjJzyE6q5IiEL5lQJfd5vveVhuUzlfiaTbnasKLQ1LsYbsy6UYnHFyqQH4khQNLyhRCk0qcmcdPHHsl4Kpo3eqwznE2IAYOs@6@2ed7jBa1F8z1t85zaSyHNEZvPy1usjWviDM1o44u0nyDAFyqynSyxJ@FCbiEjVt5WL7mb4oVt908zn9g6jIORsU2XSr8riwnEmtsm3HxP@7VoQ265XlHZML5esZrKTtp@q4xV5eKyOwoH2l2BW8eE@hy39lVmEkaUAQkcidlfmZ5hfFBgIkVNDIskyxqrdh9dl5nQ067pNMCOJzdHFhGKP@Vpbn@ZmNtOkb1EDDsIDzBSsSlfxw@7kY66MmRin/nDU2QH9DucUG0k92Z8nocssxMY9zsx0h5DZpPzZD5TV3KDoX924bsqt9s/HPrjBi1bpPmMWp5DPUQIJiCByaebntU9g7D0SA8JUyTuClsOIXlBd6zTo8nYZmOfEwypmQo67AomQYqdmJLBl9RYTdAx4ervGAQb5SnhHd9GahHLkheWRhpS1nab4Wk2NXUypgV77sQTJ5sRVOOZaXhBV7rEQnvBF78kybuIEaDbzmovQO2KsPIM7WN1Ogt6fmpxGnQzxtG/uKZkXcR85lSUYo2U0VCelpOMd8CK9Mif0lEgZG0y4Ywyc/n83MdIp3PL2esIB/mObfGLvgrjBHScwIw9Q9RRLxRhObFCJTkwPNVgy3@C0On6Z4Tf@NofgxU/5vIvHhSd458@9k4e5T/2vnz8zWFMtEg2q2xB5fRltpFYeq7Qylh0Uz@NVVpkQg1@7KULfOwp8WGxSECIFPPHPxVPvhQJoY85x3lU/JgTgqSGDJgU726vCPDFKTRzaSyKucyc88gxg59/UXYUra38F2MoLxz5S1iYTSUf09M@Z9ghUOyn@@uluJxExdWl0pOl8hPaCZ0FN4VhcIn1thBdngY3pEpE2M7S0vPxtxQ3pAjx9Sby1@jlDfVT0pqI70mknZS0CNXTnNvJxGxFdTzhCSpPVOZwqXBxceIyPi4fseF3FbGcKcuxoMR00OK@PNbPqH@BdvwIcm3SO0Q4ElYGYiPCR6gFQDbJV27jUMdMlwX2c/LUJmK3MhAa3mLOWi16/V5BK2uOt7AGJRpeM93V0mppco5OTdHUDJ3XytTCA1Vef/H0P/5t79fcKLe@VHw/pL@j3K@5ldWcPNID/Xpsfl3l1nPPUWzla25cpD0wPT79j/9N9df/QnDwZfyc/llfNrBWxrn1QpWrfMmtr9BDeWmJ2v0///zP1Id52bEhF@t801WM2JqhyKbfY96l76qBXsq2dCERK@yYBRhiYUh7c/oBw6ibpdUSH9PltFXFVaAjXxl7FL3Es2HWiE2F5CTD2FOQZiQVqmigICCNCUVHWbYbxmwDzJugqX5@6K1EtAP4WZtzxE3GphsPI5gMzcu2iAYwLy3Sfl4e1ksvsrF5RyVrbErWjAqJrZ2WtauP14gd3vaDUdhKW0mY6XrR8q@DUw986AXtS9pT9aJu/5dh8YpY8qK8tFrs4HC/yHbcxQFDKgzG3m@kCOpkQLQxZKNTVw1pBPoXCOHlcrYgUui34zspk0@StOxB0JIzrHROYioiPn6uXA@jO16iSuf5X1LgkTlTJ4K0cqV97FHNvf2Kyi7GBaUc73kdYPOWjWN1CIyCWMMOWDZ5Ge4DTgdNf7za8IydkLgWoq5LEc9vt5u@/pbPzGVNqjQ3M3cedAfVbEfCuyN2Km5MNP1FzbwVSiHECUKhwIIOsC6CkU9b9GqW32A/nrSAMCn6rjUOFZeQtaPL6l19u8pZV@5o@lqavqYRhZaQtBPzjBWNTdnFRLZUcVQ5DJq4UpvZMLUWmaTNQ4//AINIhqXRgVuC7g57QBLVku5oqzJ72FzeCxOPXAfisydHi5K5OpNLnB9dU0I8qKE7oV1PGiMBgSi4FVgo0@8D8YComjSjYS8j8fwmPpv4HhoM92EPoUTtsHUSfFSWpd4Vct@EI/alVEQCHVfWtsHOyOoRg45DbMUpaLM4eMk6YKlOhTdbXNAMR4XTQJuQUNmsnFMdt1ScXrajs9dKogh6kS2Vlx4/WV55uvoMWc7mdG9ng0ElD7uAwblPMFijztMmG@@r1exCVl4hBfV0k4A@Cywu4GDWde04JuzztfOgWi5pYKUsw7rmNBpSXR9XMsgE4jDwsCLQHiU/zObzLyrH6NjJx7bzhf4j/jbxAZnhTDhaX0hvjcPbJDJV5kICDlRZMHNQnPxjRFBx9Be7bNDv7CPaRABbV2F7amgHESBG58P@5dm5zR2eDm11SBOGCM5xqbGDehWMkgBjFlbQRfWBQ8PyvqgaeMfTPYBRLpYE6HwCnKaZjlvpa0tTzI4FWoQQWRMeq7hCtExHbXZm7uz1VX13axKxnJ2GjuF6tmUrKXccyQwBZJCr1@ruIVFXR7tgV1Itk9xUVGUWcCWUK7M7vA9f6RYSUVtUMbKa9YZR/i6ylJkXk9CmSVUaR@A1A2a59G1SGr9W0wsQxAhCfZoUCzE3vs@xSZbgZA8y5il4OVuxbETfhFHEAeZ0Y1lHW5RyIc4qMJe5BSDObUpZ6UipghHlxzonXpbRRjJH8YrG0YA2Q453qsHMkpxmgq1uIwmAjazjhhbof2N301Vbdfpn@/2WC0V5o/ZX9DtO8Xw7vmWNb7miGttmCOxosWxzC5upX@GiRMxS0gFjEwQhfDuSFTFIogbUG9ua9jKpj1Nz@yThCrCrr5VwczqqJwkCvfAZyJzevMehONhdh99V5PBqWtLEIVX0tJAjrrsntkWTuaTVGJKQ8h4gliZBxIFaEm6fSxheLNBZ8/b13sUwdmN7Nk@nWFY2VKS2bxeJ7GmevZUyd7HFkmaLpQrG8S6@YL69kzdOg05f@6LFzPEN3njwx3ijcH/mKPy3YI76P4Y7HmvueFyB7BHuiMOGs0cnp2Hvz@CY0zGvwc12eBbifKhj/UQnSq4FgAUeMIQPKX0sl9C3W8SJys/@sDi5HsFIaGkZjgF/qPNPdOefVCBz@XEr@K/a@cLfufPLuvPLFaw1M0Zeq3ZWuPW/T48TlTCffjFzeKHuSjHnj/Z0Rfd0pYLVdMYw/3/vaeH/UU@f6p4@rSBiglw4SPj6u7lZNJHawWajkZhbeBkdtCuPPPazudLB3qtdzdLmodO9jM6r0NbVH8Z/VeO/CmnET0hDh7uI2DY03svL9lSc5UWz5FMOBScr6Yn010RGt/qrF6xkP6IXKBHSfLA11BsVUshd@ZjcNnmJ/phI33jxuS/OItt1skxcnFsbaNkRlp1kiovmq5NkLq3E68oWx0BWm4f7O4v/Q8hw4X/SXmiEPIb2Ouh2zUpib8EO46hTujNWdwD7QO85UqyiycnIjrS3d8wuc7dLNQ5sMbEuzt4kyFUb7v9oL3UBfcPKyo0jI6KNp@ubXRVMc832Qt5Q36XQ7C7rHv8hLn2mufRZRe3rjcFtpPL1gZ/mxWSftrS8fNcaILU8/MEELLlU/o5Z9X8B)
• [diff](https://www.diffnow.com/report/rjnz6)

Windows and Linux binaries are available [here](https://github.com/stasoid/-Befunge/releases).
Command line: `BefungeLyt --98 --d=*,* --cellsize=32 --quiet polyglot`.

`0k` is noop in !Befunge, in Clostridium it skips over `^`:

```
         >"473",,,@
@,,,"368"^;…;k0<     IP
```

Answer (score 0):

## 406. [xs](https://github.com/TieDyedDevil/XS), 17160 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{   #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\';     `"<<rc #"`;     a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;  #{IO.puts 295# ['];   print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68')));[exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';  #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + *
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._eg=:
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({e2b510ae-b02d-444a-9503-b278b885f0b3}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4saPh@REpUFUkRQIgAL4pUqVSqW7V7Xp1lere6yZZLJAESVyBAAsgJbIkVXT37Pa6bc@sp8ee8Gt82z3r2fZ6IsY7sbNu79gzEfZ@nHDMJ/@A8mNjw7Hh/ge955wEQFAipbpte8OxIAHk82TmycyT5@TjoGv4o5/8JIEXe@bai6HtTtnU9Kes71knpiezuwt2x7D8gqYLAoba94azselM/aqQYCpjtuEMZ8bQZAPLnppelvmmybqm7Z6Cv8bY7syZ@Wa/ATadMcc8ZQ@dntUHCGzqHpuO9db0wC/P2D3TPh@fT1nPHY8Np@@ziWc5U/ItMPbMAMtg1jtmRtefekZvarkOeBUZe@nYxrjbNxgFn3gmj1RiAKp3THFWfcqMPXY934QU3J7p@y46VsDR8Cz30f6Tjy6FV3PsIwMyNbHN@aXkVZV9aple/3IMjX1ydP/@ZVedfU1yHXb/apbUPNufTd2H08vwC2x/aDoG0@SKrF32LAIyp6ZdzpVzl71KUJ/m1OqtpAMe9y0PatcIapH1DAdqC@tyh5njyXTBJF7/hm1Hdeszw2czf2bYFM6ZjbumFwb0p4Y3tZwhO7WmIzYdWX4Uj0L7E6NnSn3TtsbW1Owz24JI7iCAAqCdPjs2F6euB1UewHQdewERzZ41sDBKmA8AiFdqOjI5nLGxgEp2ptA4mMF8yIZthtDSQgLC3zO7syFzZ9PJbMogb33LN7o2AO0uWN8cGDN7mmVd8AMkk/vpyHSCxgzgZABx5PJcfT6jrJnLNm/0@ywH7RjycWwyC7BG2aoyXQd35nqANQgV5igARu2al9GcQ51BFQ3cKivkcuB/GLlgbg3bd4PMrGYNPR3oq1RnCPeZ5w49YwzY6JuE008ePmN@z/XABjeG5f3pOjA9Y8p2d1ny8Mm9JGtE1SJ7XSGqojo7gypIhJ7sxLBn0ELiNeFC/XhRbAGrLLmVrLIkoEXLsXye5aHblplWACSpuQoYoP9rugp3kWllllehBxWYrpWSWUxr4BlDyzY5pCFCKmHjhyAaPHN5pqtlHnLo2gMerEcJlpheZsUSKxVYCZ4VVtEgRQSfZ2qlAHcRboBWgeyocOuQuZzGgS3bP7RXbHMHbGCMLXsRpEBJ9FhBZSWACvlWAbpWBijw1nW8dbgpa6tXHPZ0BFgfGScAXrKtY6RKZkSYsCoVeCk7OwpRRiS9PHl/hMkDCgF5hTIrQfJFwEYesgAY1sqQfCHHC@KPTNsOoo18jEa5LeXghpyXABdlqIUc4DOHCC3BDXagexoQOA2omQYESgOiomlg1jEJCFcEvyJUaTHPkxkZ/jEkxNPR@lQBQNkBjIoYR2KmIpIAAtQYA1RDdeehQejYIAo6g/xDXkpFBvSsrLJynpVLDPBZyTGoHxXyha1FBTqqQn5UBAZtQIVGoEKeVMC2CkBVvcCEGLJVHf0hrg5xATVqHuLkwQwVpxbxhnjQOlRIUoU0Na2ybIyQN60A5S3o1Eq1ItRuCfwAbxrkVYMmpUFutTL4Y9wy4LCMjRiaLkeEgXiAWsFmD20RkFGA/BBcCAtmraRz/Bn2ZGR0kWrzmN0BRi1idygiGiFqDosH7zxiE7KSAzDYEyD7GrQAnXoNvPNR8rYKQJoI3uxbRKhtC2iYGmGolKUG@bkxmS7RphYpR5PFdBS5adzNBQJqARE0h0ZvEXlCD8xGnkvXoo6uGtHcJaBcHl19oLDuzLeXQCJDXqOkzBPLXrqVya1vGv2B5Y/eLfOap0S6pjF1rONlKoVCNoZUI@ZRRI8Vp5IeDzu1JBi2hiM0LcuilTDMxI0qaCXLqkrZ65qDmTM0pUo5lj/ymc68KQwwyzQr3NmzhkMYm5dw1CwVkwbMpXOBcmjr@lSIHBG7mKZnwTB@m/VGwFhEnhUOv1JZwtA1hLEwuji6S8CNwWhQwfFrYM1Z93aPRo9lBnXCU29kTcLA1Y2BY5VLiczLxVjbIMy9Leci8oxXW/7ctZxUkiXTwoUAYw7nMOMjNgxsn@JoheMvNl0YX13iHpbkM@WEI2QakLY62MPoawMZhUrpGTgS47hk0rgawrGmMoNEgB003RNkX2lwXEnGpwG06yG3CtxO3/Q8hmGBxfWzNNT6s65vvpkhP7XM1wDGbhOG@IFh2VEGaBwxpsQIwDvpQ3qL1WwPPHdMg80Yh1LbdScb2BYYuE8R0AP31FxmfTmuG5OJDdwTuJuceYPMnBrEdxOTHk@VZwgiYTyocABISQHXYXlmj3AfFB1i68CfrGaxyrTGbR2h3I2xVTp0FmA5fIzjzGy7CvyO2WN6Q@mbJwq6cNZrleXCPITMGLBUAYiuATwz5pxyEUG6rcnE5h2FNeu749Wi8fH1YVT0kYUMkn1qLKD2BjC0mnNjDJw9Q/YZei4bQ4vhNYg1AbILFush67tOchpBOfWAmYVCRyUhhhlxMrXGJkhBLkTBGs9TpnF0p5x1F9CUCVt5mcQenpNLiJKFy4jiDvmYA@8swPb1Zz3EGqZtOdSCgFXykdf3gFRyN2HqsVbLgNsDvm4SSHoyGjDgC8xaTFDweW8POPAeQURe1XR8EC98mVkoh0HLH7oDaGynFpQdCBZEXcLuERIQBZHTXO7JAqEcG9D42GYW600mDNxhUILmeT9XBlbU/dxib8HTHoEo0Zt53oLNJ1AT1hhCTXvuYACt9605GQEINu6z3qIH3RMqGVuP0HeJwPQmq8Vc2rZNCOOgcHLw7GfZ0AS0A@M6QCkVm/yyAJMJFYFQYTicqXUMwBQWoTdZEFqExDLGwHVldO@7pk@NxfWOo66PifnmkLoG9LPBkhiNkUmHVuqQcNEHyhN0L4SPCQprC4NJBa3gI9OBrtODVgmdHqoP63SfDUDYjrGwKG8YvZ45mQbtxCVyZjkxvv/pfeT7yVUKgMn@SNi@w3YvtRoIGrWcGC@LchBmfRKIIwbS2kCil4jxiERPTlnsxZXkIcTJpdTF1xhmJQevxQ15mFCXQCGIiMRsiqQEqaPVGyEtnCK1IX4beps3u1p8cIsn742ZNIjSxtyoQHYEWYmcMB@bYUhw21cByRMbYTVWHDDoisMNoA1/vAayG2XS7sddZcWQgSjeBHTsOu4aqIDMCC4GWfWhuqDG@AKphmFHjZG6i79SR0iwl5NMOJDBGDqZuB70DE50FjSjQFUWa12BIJ6Kxoq0zO6uDq0wZCRxwJ/iKAgRJrYBbQG7GPZUkKwMoBRAxLigDDTP5SnGMky9nmAF@Tsl0s8bE4yljmOicGZ4Cw4EigfDMyS0YJbnARk8wUGCj0HhYCJTO4Uxwej3kbIiOqjfX05cxhZ9MOta88vSeA8d5c994cTw2AAFcQ@YDuhEqeTAT6Zr5E4xY16i4k6mCkXlTxECUiAZqjw1ANkeBon7QGheLJxeSlzpYmKWibPpoCymwYAROY/GPgZR4XLuUHzARjM@hn5NthobwvAtSfCU0I1ygh6KjB6GB3wGdEKQMiuVftdg50A9PCbND7goEookqpyP0jKdfpRWgAjMS7y8Mk/C93pkkGKjGpYAg1PJaZBYQeAHYoIiiuCgKMHYig7E7XE/4mu448yh@TiW4qxImp1FzC8MACnKjAXMh9Wzpp2AXbl9O2Rctup1aGzATQHZ7KfjEm04cSkDpYbAMnEjQSLy1H0xxb6RSkN5MfAFzw2wTdBS6w12Nh150OPIfiFAIECr4GBLDhEb1PMT63jWv1zRDjpiIBF7HTBNVm8q1gQY/HlvqF@H1eQKVkHqTSJWsfFifAJ9pfGSK1aoGATzTB/Z33qQlVgNpzAHQVtdiyIeNXBbNuiDRc8OWAJugs7OqVEXsn8cTGhFhCgb8ARhp73SUzkQ7A4cDnu2f/SgHvRF7ql0Lae64mC7PcMm520MLoZxHz28@3z/@c921sCwrW71soNi5ctFHGpnc2nozJS8rFW34zCWgO91roeNEVfDiELgzSR3HmOVFj0YXOYhOp8@/9pllAAnhOigFMCM9yWWhocBpkvoGv7o0iDMhpkMJBlFCcMy6SELYUYGzDr6G2F@ns3evsXKu5ypSeCOObNnBgcQOioPnTCejJ6XGLDQqzvgIyLFBS7UcnDBYWmKhwzz8xFyzZczQ6x0rMl89PT@4fM6gQ3m1SQKovhT4KUMry9Dm7dnIIKvCwPkD0w9lpGXGUd@mvK6FsG93gqCl3XLNsAHACjryC6T7HFYNH8EeT@4XDZylXpRCyA7QbjMV8b5od6XzWgsHzjE9VDkXTeKksdysIqc1o5Yke/qsNUrFMxSvhIftnrLNPtxoLQ4AONAyDd64HXsS@giL7nIgK0Osv/i0ZWM@8REgigghTnzbSZTWr4toPQiWSzpKwcgobm2KX9KFE9kYlpRkuH6gNzzSfiMhT@cW9NULs3fahrCQur7@w@1e2HgYMqaZjJIaEBZHEcmb4DrfD0f2ojj2u7QZTsQh3OHYYLANm0s5v7Qda7UkIGOWNQELhUC/cWJG2MCY431lgRHihUXV/mio@H4p0Cl1aKOSCIMESiFwsufGycGoGtZ7hcPv3EIg4hayOUic44uQEEsDqELTb2YKzkwCRKSg/ysLWC0bHilt4ceUmzdDgsdELoo4v7Se60jUUxZWRt@bZY@dq9g/HN3calpgQtvWmCIoezhk2ePHj45fLz/WWuqFQor9nyuUgTEQXpd4IXkEccb9tYd3jWxWAguAX3Dw@4FVGAGAkq4ajTzPSDcMgaReQY2tBq@4Jr62B05ST99uTCn6Ct97vR4E3qMnY8HDSKCoN23URjx@Ko1jufYfkbT6cSvKgr08tGsK4PQqnzec21jqFA8GBhsW1FRdHn4FOc1/HUxIDP@wuQx@OQWsA4LmkE07LELwgutfSNpYCkOnmatbGs4AlkYF8hNLy1HLZhKo/RBQgBZWYnKRgSYbIDb4B3Wk8ib9ldVrczbtZrT8ooYBlvp/hB2a2CC6JSC0QpQkb5kZa3brdtsAVQaIV0GkmDyDk1y@AzHApsBI0mzpijnh8ghaoHzpUgrCEdvZjibC1RKKeTyJbVYUEAsAzENeFYJ59yksTHtjaSpKwE8yR3QvEGsFQ78nuEM5J3AEGYW@L5bUFS9@arVctrAoLduU95w/bm5aDfVdrrGrkbZCcKna9B6V4qHbTd0gLZLRmia9GYb6FnfuErO@gb1rj5TpuNJMOZIE/Z4Hxipty7Q674Z73sYQYl7KjsrYRUM/E5ZMyFkY1QBH4gpBToUjLTQ9BTMlwRML7KH0HKAbsUisOVsRsQwLaYjoB86Sx2QKX2Vw0VnPaAaq1nBSWF5sgCSR4GQaEs6Zij0oAQnHAJmJQkiEHI86J/kWeBbTWKkDOV@7HqWm/RpmQZZK5yw9SdQjzTf3cOBwscpyikM0FHnw4EC2heOE@zUTOJUvuHzCVOIFGw3COODuBhBoIWBaFLciTZYQDukWDRDAMQLmjbO3I6WE5047wCNHRKkPOH8BzAxDi1gDKGQEJkXZJ8XhKdELqtFOnbcUwehdU1WlrrWlK83uDMPl92tfrxsEFzXeBiARoWLDS20Pt81e3yil0emUoAcarCxOXZxNgMYPKJGJhXB4Gv7KI76OGkOPTsn4aIlwJfYnQMgpD2TT1lJY5TjoFUfsuTUU/albyiG9BY61DXsHRY@VsVBpR@FCFjdaUETNcEkLDFI7pgCfUpTPuh5N@S4g6aFLUs06u7EdC6LnVwoTaVrtCMimeTrUGfJra2tZDXZSGbBtAemXTTtoSkDpj0ySWTCcDKaKEaWTOjbpBjo1k5eNEPI83Qb28AcmZe31iRlNKtVvZ01mmrw1vCdhqoAzENoCV8AJ5mu19GYTouNU1w2AhEiVvYDbDsvep41CVDwMfAk3B7vXmLQvTyzhuLx9RgZ1z2QW03kclNestXMtdqts1Y/07pIZjF2umbUQUQF@jlNjeWh584mwDs281UJyGu6qVfbtW49mUvupFJlyYaEjHT6VjmdMTiuU0kT2lSq1UoCSgPsNHsjj@DNs1o6HSEK8jGwQNCx7VRSPitD@t10O51JQtx0MgsjQz2ZBLzQmqdPhcZJCd6I7ltzQCV0TBhl48saRKNpfQy76zfMyWjhxQNEE3/A6OMk/nLbDO4uwoEkTqjf8vhxnnJlsiFkvXk44K9x/hBZtsmCDzACz2lLWdmkFQ79J9Jg7E4N5RMZ5DY5NmInt5KKJMFgTD4cEhX7seVjFzYc05358cnOtXOwmDq4Ho1mQCzDnXJZaFXWRDB7I5clt@8AdBYtOSHhx9Uzia/BhQD6PRluJKLIGOF6DTA4tLfJArpIu8JoYkilTHDSEy4PFIqTN3KUWo3isBwmZA0d1zMlQAnEEGgjF20PFBrh0vhDmny7MvwEvjSq4lBmmUAR79uuQbjl5Dq2JDUZx@I7Q4zy3OwLNtCPAZBHmdeFZ/aVHYEWil1vBCMElAYpsRbV1jjwUFx/0penc4gqpHDMj3tyARP43lPW1zSt2CsMqqEftgpA9ggqCQVjB6Ts0EtSwTMdVPIhn5kKpwmePL13yKdvaLzHER6n8jpjtz8D1jYQ3Z6bzjDLDqE9WY47tgANYfy3x/Zz153yiQawbJoc4nK7NZ7ZBk07XZ4ZujZez@26Ns1GXRd1GX7m@YZt8Hmw0Hf/k8cgbrw8elGXq7FAinEyvjZtnApdnyzH58P4sict@YYrVD5vmOJ2QcRxK9yAimQm8CiixyzYfgp1FLqX0D3sUriME7iX0X2MW0@BXQ8mMsgaOQYBKxQQt6Pi3rvA8UzNXaD7RjEwCqdSOM67LnN7pmrkfjIdDFacdXI@lpA02UvnPDnzbakrYmo8SwUeCPeoroSJAypSmGir6sZwJQrHN9jI0eLm42gfxMi0w9XN58Cx4AoeDPo28lUgN6GUwLeTmsDkT3Chhkg3Lv@xHvDB/hUuFjrbROKhhcQWdSAY3BRkaYRthQXT7zXqQo4bLJv6nKy6XpbP7Ow2@EI7inUelygVvjCw3QEQu41auOdvUzBMKZmMghFUyhvEoGLS3oIrRY12ivg03y9QlJrgKyDRzLWc1JqXDtvnScUnNAyY2GrNb@W0z0A0wo2b27eVoVmjbVYb8FULfZIBD9tdMAk4PgzF5857I6AzLDNfRSXUz8wZuHZf4gt10GAYF/GwgoJ9EtGG0mDfsGl54V5S2szLoyJ9jW1DvQL3UpU2rgaIbVyNAEH3OWPnx9mTc9aEIe9E9ie2NW2zC3nqdkbBZi3n8hZXzoN6nrHwhWCbTZ3tP//ok2auzSEIYwMX38q8FufhTmlgnIFRwi3tYMLNQlNrSpwAbYawsLyqDJma0zoNZB9g8ARqLEooKBFm/dw8X5ZlYIKwnDIx5/5inGVm@kIe2MZ0ajq8zfEV0M3o5ktVQTJ1Sn4vWPeoshwtDgFnaqEfZLHGXhzdO3z@XIaW66eSh7iIVIXuaPRGwKBsKnSIyXjhq@xWP8luYZw0zhwI0NVA@ugE8aFR16DRg/wBqSPtGJpeChzTuP7TA2dacqOInEMLEIRbvnpTwlEELGWmoUwErLo2/y8dLmoF@axCi88QJgHdqdtVwK2VlmeO9Ub2YaAhvhWCBMIqjBf17RRRsW01HezpG@PqNUhYxDRCCZpNJr0FKgeBRdZu1/g2BAiLApg3ROyKIlUFbaivq2HV18EZWBqCEESvv2Ovmjmp0s5srwNF@9uCvfC8/DG4CGEVtG@uTXY7Rf39SkfmeeDLkZxyvyRx@tJBkCrb5gaRT3tT8HDPFhEd2uK1ulVrdSMYdDIkJTQbhAUJSUIiOKkQtFnyJ8oPMg9GI4dUmp1FSNcQ5ez8nHDItjVGOASTynhlXITSJxCmRy6U5lFwSiHOHVBvDfayYJ9tCWIoZq0uFqMPZ@GVk0vcqXQixuNx7tByjl1acopMnZysFpAjjGKPj@2rMXEfLD1WgkZ54GG1Tbnzx90BPdYEoJWXYE2fHGhOP@CFgYk0lOf0oun9NSmv7mNZSTbYIUsjLZiZ9OaGkFKlTIEH3a61KSggAbemhe81wYBIYXvW5LyshscecCoGxiMgXFx6WRb98hYotoL3YCtv8P6v3@wD/q/WzggGCpz8jAwdGLqxpqTBxsoKoqKFHusrls/Rz2zLIMSQ6SaQPcODIhl2ZFgPmvYBSBIM/2Nc1QhqHNomPoBrvKaZ8ZzzRcnwvT6Rdet6DpDM3qawl7aE8aRoBQoEuz4hgTNBlkmRiHTxSjDnfBUoJmIjGbs5U@G@LUaNmdf7aDad8ScwrjdWojXB@7q@GYTMFYyuaip88/w1Ve4Zx7O@K02OhxGfWlwTdll6WoaWgB0IVqQ7aFxffF5Avhk9fG8KthzalFN63dQqfGfmT6QuSeF9bqOOML4mBc/mz01BrOAcYWTYjDXLpscHtsQAOjSUYEOGgttdpRjSrEtoto3uAnmQ0ZdvZdHmBqA49V4mk9M3rG5PJpvjoyRJ8SuV9bHnco/jY90cgcK31Ep8Fo0KHGyyvaFWYbiyxoYtaf2YcSMxX7c34krQaFmV4uD5DzoEcm0jxwGpN7MNb2m6pokv8xEuI2yakQ6GjWdWzwV2YMLUkqxq4dARGzCIZIa785YJ4Y5mesR2YFjr0BieaJEi03oS4PamuGt1Q5v6AILGd4vintxYI5HdTZjquad4b2QfRiCa8uf6Ee3t2lx9AHGS7J5twDi@cThYmRzEyccbGuqp5Zv0WI/Y47UZnfbste6rXSCc9otP493UrH3Ldn32gp7XIWjoARb4c32DjuPSMhyJJsPj5mtoULjNYlmhhj107WJ5qBjw2FjrM2@AdD94fyiFiyiUqt5AoUL2x3XU4L2Rrh8r3vFNFURnJj3cYhszXjPEriNTwdrL5tKBYIALd@tLdj9Xppiywqf6NiSMSy6nxiJ8/xRDxybUhkPHZEHsNHB3GKFSBsPU4yz2T5Na/vrU@h9GlK6ALd1UiFjlHtsmDFb0vFKlTMupXzKGmst9OIka2DNzZq4VNJ52PzfxhP81QsaHZyoXFGM7mKnHxQE8HROFehtIhh@Uaxyn0XYtMTFsq2fezMqsErUJcN8TFJ2fgeEZGq7GGDqzyUqtrkhnzvPrUTaahF3a7a/kDn2@LB0q38AprfDnvkn3tRITl/Bwj1q9kMvlAgYmtuKyYrlOktKjuJ9b/LmSMLksU16GxVU2L2ZcnwahJb4LciMJ0jYJ9hS4UlEcyzGnC3x@IDXtuq79ZWoKiCqeWXZBWpVot@91NXaF3QnOsbDl1IWPEx7dwaZJCz7aBLIl4AeF5usqPb4k9EG1KeGi5xgXpFat10/fxBaYbkoFz9finBDf/2tv5iWD2RBVLsula3sd51Ddrmkb/DUv5q@DV5H1a@GtEo1gsRYXd/mS7nIpPnGJKE0WgCyrD1LKyBybZL2Gyzf6qK0jeG0MNHfx3uQ9N82eMj80e5sCTCygCw4@V9aQY8zS1HVAvpriVkOUU2zczBq4bqLA4arfWiQ/HBtDk6uPuY5SLicscDcNF@uWxvVTF1W@g6YH0ZZ6QTY3CehUx@bCD99rAT5e9KBeZ@Obp9sudf4ezoF@QG/ftIv26hDrjNyRMzJHfOt6ZNvUOaA9Trm6n@uyDrkejnA33WSysss@jk/bte0PwSeSRk4oXXewNk@HeP4WD499Kbj8sH/wunHyzphy2oGGjb1mZM5gXPLdqTsxJbJtCmrjRA9/bqKh4SL1TzuDdK2cDxgJ3z8t/Btly6HhTicTenUm9synB0WV6Nj0TXzTgG9NoX2ZrjeU37rjrhw4ysG@FVoCX09iuta0N8Jz67xlm0O32xtZN2U60JWhhFM@3PpBsitixmLSPXSWbQvQ6y1kbC/1uP8LfD3cVOnB7BEf1iLDNfzKuhk6OhkuTYzjns9nQ9HEqjghHOuN/Px4lU7gV9/MrOkSaGwvUzS9y5cl0LAp78HuiY2cFR3TWJLhYFfFxlZKTDoy5JKZA4ZH3ZTs6j63WBfTdf7YlKF4KSlHsX0pXwbdwd4fmh20YvO24L7SvlY2La0d5JzRbOhfJZh8ur4PLBo@Nk9b0Hbq2JQ1jFmGE7w2oVmzFTxnCe8O8Fwz89o1lcK1iyoUTrUlw7Xg1YEXVN1s4xyabU18/mTSYONSXLCXCWTxy@uFHDeL9cJ0UDF9c8CXQNB0E4s4dj3ciQw8iNTDlXScQUdizhkvTrgcdwhEXbLZMnAYdhPbsnab0Prqj8ZM6bMn5tDAvdaPrClu1lzTKqjJrttedCPsr88M3/r6DEq2qbGh0gi@DOnFtQugbQ28x8bQ6j1YqYgokwGCg52e/LXS/NHpal2cjiwfdzRFhmsmprDJ8UaMra4DcsOakJfn7SN9GcsOxE9irg29bm7dnSzwwNqCTNdNq1tTmmUN3ptEx02bwK7NxOlsPJn5wWt9HmjPVHwWenxM7v6pBcClN0Ba2ciwp@tnqmNTrsCFBYPi0riJG/@GZbtD9o1yjgHTBkwYMudrGs5dGJ6f4YYcz1nTEintD1z2xIkOyeMFewN1a@K5CseaXj@bM53i5pzwjYXhIweeUFAe4VO@82UhSEfrMfLoZl5/eTr6hvEdWt4Ld@b1TDRGKk/iYkGQqnkQ7j7GEx0uqmw5jUtpPdeG7gUGe22X6bnObCp5M@faUaF47ahQRYVXsWbAUl8/fPwyHW8NtFv7Ji40VIm2NG3cMHCpkVkOMGKb6ehq6FCWuMdVNT2nrcI3xNlHfVI9Itf33HXyzrMFDCAfLDAB8Z@N75k9XDa8Me0n7mPXcWE0mgChHD83udqBlY0e6yNitEd4sB7w078xmRcEdsMgxLkNY2J2oX7tpelDxiIO@J4xNTYMRTQ3SPJfZLqxrVh21/Q@p0m/mHmTSLuaoQfmnGSLzQ2G90Fp2utxlhjn41b6yMqKjT9xXYc/idrm4KU@vp6qwFBAjw9fKJdxI/7KvMBa@Wy1qE9P@C4Rs8/1Ymwqq2d2XZs/r9mT5Fh8T4DhWaavPEI1C@RWzDMJuC//WhpSupaGLEUj4GRPDJ8W6deLGkuQ6vxLbAEaGV7PxZWwwHDN7pyYboQbyHS0t59vHOgC4udAsYzeLNBXelO27HF3TI@NAkOsNp@bXTwV1CWFIlNjfrUy@cxQoE0htqMr0kEQkivs1EWWegbSSPrmYWtFjlrFqjWhB1HqjcvltFlHciyz99bAWTOX8LWcm17xhzIrT8i4Ya461o1oFlkx6LD92p60unUNGBrblKYjD2R@ZXrd9Hao6WXNeshsbOIi8@oqzEbW1fVHVFh3/Xp6RFw9UwrUDQItiVQPcv5Q2t/IeSJ4@D@9@7ECg3CnmA@1nwDpunkFHzI/85zg9SEt8JnrTwfW/CnkG08BbCInWKwCRIEX7xlo2tlUCKg9Z2bz2YdhbN/VuE/imEQKoSXJJnI9NSXTOZFIF938aolcfuhL2UcFwlOzLwWqGHClQXoUnv@KggXvNQuocdqImz1VhSN2XswH2z/XIfc0pAzAb7lTaeLTW5n4zx4@enokT3x17fi0P8LTEVf4uBXdDlo5F5uS@tzwYuudfDta3/Knyt0XqnTw6KGMATbgm69oSPDClbmV18Z5z1CRrGJslILQ15yuZxAfHD1@lFke0WSpg5Hnjs103PvgxYssnjT5@MVa73js@9A7Bu58Y/SHh6qaXtN8Xzq0OriJeq5JaROkIxOkUWiMD7hqmBuZq547MftHi4n5CQyeSMH9D0y@uLGQT4wTa4i9kFU2Ioo6KqvIxXw6tjMbhG3Ti96b6vPYmiC17NFL4a@N21GQc9AVT1/PPVy34n@Zi2G5YCfCl4uk5q621rgqY8Xw/64ZU1V1E55fGAOoV1bYWFmrAdatD9vuyQcsJZuB8CJFTtIUWpVk3biPvCSNgXQr@MDp@cARjN2N22CuAxA5F9d2@FPTWRiORGtZ17EXVYiNm9quDfIN8wMWpKIdPieoL33tGl@0pZ6lemRM35DwkReLcnBw9@FNEZ4HuLw@1EdPXrJnho96UK4PGM@x@QE5XnJGn0s4b4VK@DYup/Y9AKVdC284Wd@fq@yF4fVdZzG/eRGOzqDi0E76jSNYaKNApm3NrXVjVY/Paz1bv83oprT5IQ53scIHx/XjBIDef@dfqGouR9qP8K3muPWGmgk7OEuhyVigSr2419HDiDT0kG@RwSG9Vhp9ZM5xOwqfDV4n1K8d34rXjH2l9Obh5Dq/8jV@@WvSu@KHjkyXc@o1AAvX@LGCHHk/cu3TkSsfGJ7pr9l/vDZD1xWkck1BKjHqHChsp4XFwLyZxcejC8FrbWs9MqdefjJyu1Z@bRn2B6jnkj1Gfe1X/YPtFIZH21uGbnDkg9vXp3c6M9cm9Nh4u96DKM3xWi8gguZoRkcirnqvLpB2gec1naHFVTyyu@70kGzXCGbRief1exGsyb3ZZHOOgTbiVzEuk/OVgJ@CzOye@uwuHo1bsulrZH/cH7fefRNPy6KJQdR0@uBoP2xdT18oWizFZS4@e7bijIdHp09fxNw8cz7fJPRK800y5FqfZapPjvIrye42Xp2sQdbm80bAbgA9jt4b@SBO7D5@cZUkoPg2mo7t0Odjw1nOmK5UWN@d0knDtZ7PFnPaRrm2pkd8F9s6P6@3xnlFsIcB2bIgbV/pdFAdU6ezqVUemZ/R2gOwQWzK2RIONFC8ZM7zozCHFGVjR3WPl8zPSnZfTEaWM1/rNd4Uh3aRpj7313eDffbCdk/Zo0ir0CbyoK0HbpyYzibitO6wolTRr@fC9Ess1aZ64R9QCV6bquTuJkbtEs3ADRHXUROM/7yn3A8tn2jpG8N//CIMfnPYA9vF@fu@NRvfHJjAZjI3B/SuIX@XAVo3B8PvjRyPXM@5OWjYnKrVu@YHZmLrg0OOFz33A/LQHQxuDnTouzcHejyzpxbKLOuDPnFnNmoQWOd36A3Xujd2G62WXJU3eaJCd3/kpTf7475Id@aDDGRFxDOKKH1uTVccwzYTd0P98qYjO276EtyPXfY11CS/BhVvP7COPr6/Kdzqgs0Ml/jpRPDSuGlT72Sh39jJ31pDsnxIp3Os8bVhlyr/Hnquw23pTcPjUv3fmpQeGLZ1I0ELNzxoN2x9wAGN@7MT/WaqBQzC/c119slivhQ3V0tvc6UT6/wONEDKsNdLhx9Bwq3pqh6b9OP7z0x/87Qfjf5fPxwbPT9saOjEtxeEC8hr@F6ulQAGtfhHNfxsoJOMa/HguhN8OfzySSrlQNtPr35mLq4IAlXPp7ZR9fI2KX2AsOfnbCtQtAAeYqi6IVAtgRpaLWdmom4I/vGpaX0bkqnX1UKF7eF33apMzVGa@MnKCleEGSbWZNtngdqEalW9YFt1JlZFFiiuiPTac93sABi1SkOhmHSssu0p@GyHShcYfWaInTOaK5Z6qLwXbLISVz9TC9RSQJ62z549fHb44mj/6OWLZq59EaitCEvhOJBaqBznlt4XofAB3kAG5V9qIHUpNiRHn0DCOWY/LBfDz6qtFq2@UrRlocQ9jLN95jiKQpo7FOkC8ieJPDXyRU4KnDjssMRUQYHSlipXokG6QKCOOGiR0oRKq7LcuoQnBshT207gf/krhOSLX6us4vcqMeFAuT60xKHr9oMUfZPdfIUp3t9/@Ojl80MWZnDZak6t/nRUrxT4txe4NiGop4FFW5nrLBlESUJd1evJ@0lATFJOsirpWqHvHkBDh2AhdlBLSxB7h6W2CT5gMBlVivJfv6lcJGU8lZOGsMkwU0lIFto8NZStrS12BI2E3Xv@8JPD5wzzf3iPnBFFCIIdoaKHP/1hn385KFTEFn6p0xuT8EOKrIS4spdQA8pSSQvinPruZPP3OulLPaQKJfpEUPSNM0GgL0hBuz0lNa6X9GumSeUd/75ooP40TIiaUPi1EVwARlWmSFYt30JFLJiHAWoWXW3suGeUFPrKbB8/RoqfPDXoM1aQ9Zkz5dr7Ah1eCWhpckRzsmybMss/eiXGAiZ3t6Cxd02Qi5nvWDAyT6vsc2iJuMha5Yp6JKmRvBIlBF0lk4SyVCzgFVWkvtLylPe/9M@UYY2BeQrm7wbmee4u2H4hsA3A/Ivc/ErBhnZVdekyL/EMocbjoAQ8IxH@Efexb7A6XDnSEnGoYTUkrMwaQzWdENYxOE@BPyWgx0s4qeYnUGnQ3KDGAqVIPD3Ta6dQ5XJVUbBJ4VyNTAyGOef7wy@pXi4WinlVgUxKJyFA@lbKEBVfcIDpdBW6iXBiTeqvQf7f3d1lIk7YmvVijdessu280sXXUUa3IawAAzpkrskgDkRZxgC/RhANRp@MmsaoSL2SahIJV9@FYYn8cfhCuxMgQmQpQBbHkYkf35jj53qnIMYEKsS7@IHb2He0tgNAkgpjEpnSohCoE3riTqH5QCddfimPqxPC8xF8CETFuD7/iDVp7sb2KF/tWUstGOEHu4K@JiMN4KD03OXRNF634qcI4gWCqIrrmm/zFWtNW05b4W2TQTP9/prG7ID555XhhjbLy71/VWly6rLKY0QWu/PCcXFm@j4UhqU0RdMVtZheFimfX1ukoERBMlAc1Mx2DskBmQKS0TOtz92Jv39w@PDjp89eXFEMTCGTl4MB3W/sZlqSnG22I0MyXqzVKrl7X3nx@O79sCKWmS7GqDEQ/qAk6nUlWS44IcjlAcbLRVuXw8ul25zjT7mKk8v51bXrskaRruRDzX2JdOkQkXSfjgJfTlwrr8NWoXBdlpbwlBjoA67H4UpWU@mzi2YbxEInkbzaEtZ0hFcJeQc7AZha/s62go39auGwYNHn5Y/wg51@vC/q6/uiuK2j3klUIzN1j5eaOQOHmEesvGEyQCIFWQmDbux9TzmTvtQfqwH9x/zRyBBXxxfLcDF3HcZjoKiowON4SEWW2q8Dxc8jENlsqyuEahC5AuhQT22k@5mrMEylheAzTjzhFD@bw@bVuUw7hlNppHYEK8uu0yUdwksL0KGRu3s2A9HxmTvhn/WgnWH3zND03AXye2/GZ5JN9vFsDOEG9Hpu0io9UG4JIgMmk1FWOS8FVCJQJT3PoLJuSK@JCqWDgsvjfiE1T8sjc963hkDbU@ksULRbqtpmkbppLDSpl3aSItXZshau7YofoXaOONq/lM7x@TIDRtOQLadvzlPJ02S62ob00T15@ulJMi2ua0uk@zxQBt6/rAQ9yn5JvZ6SGNOgd4YaxtdRi0rlKpUAt8uAuTLO8JuClYo88gX6RmwdOfcXU@8RGIGNSA3GxoSlZg5XZCozsqZaKSdLGh6lBleS7LBMhgQqeJGHzCjmgEx8/E4ZzoKllDp@RhhcfaePr7fWhDVVWW6DmRJJs2381ucBcFyo2jctgBAMUaoEto5NCMQMyBHvJDJv4BAH/SEsvEgd7Bpv@vQhLWa6iBMqNWvcZrFvt65yjmKlUg0qdJUqVhi0vqvkUFYA7BU6F/L1gN1AxxngDMRfWUgsCflVipegdBM8Iw8C5WiQnURMsXmoM40BrKXa8d7Iwzt16EBfAf6gWn15dL9TTisii5SsDT2rj4vt/PMgkYgXfNANuqmyEjRZ4xLdRxgN1dl2uBY31Kp6nzqMeImkJuJoCFSCh8Kyv2ybqnptqw8iBrUAIfM4AASH0TshOFRBHE5arfFbT@x/8pMEMhupbVU97ngnmWQhV4OHWiuwAru13ZKk7WaufmfbAClq@mbeAplc2cmfmPdGg/7DodISRaazvKLsnJ2dJe/vPLNeFVhR6lta8c18caEX9TfzC10tvzmeqMWm/GbeFsv17HG71WyzZ88@e9d5lxbnJ4s3ImulQNY8eCqqeTFRrbCzvaKeOK7gR85BvDlmb@E6HjD8k/ltP2Y20NwdgAibFFmi1QKMq2JJVJRmsg1/Evdfw8UF/2ZDbsh77Xfv0k3DmM4XzLKsid/vw@2OgIPU0i8YyMu3gdLzCApr0ZskKLgK4zkQu31zOJwdGgtrdn96Ry7JZVmLzS7sPv7Gp8FV@/TlS8Zespcv3z7fMBfRzmRSktQk8/ySX7VjFBL4mfI//dHWRfbsWWf3T781VswtfD3F13cvHqP5hVq4tbV16@7dfD6raRo3P/vGs5/d39/P38sWnjULe3kpt7X7J3@8taVpu5qy1fZ9tZ1sHh9/Jmq5vCj/6Q@SnWfPvu77Df3//Oa7hoqPEjxOWAnoBFw6U8GIzzLcKvJYH3ol3iaglauJBf06idD9bIupjb3Sf/vlp28S00RDUz714D1NvEkUywluBAPY9NB2kmgkdjFY8SKxUOr1OhhL/@3fQ/zGxwAHfRa78GgUQljFRaIh1SnKeaJRBIOqaZDu//3Nb8ZyyMlEndi48LrDmnCJ@ZIm7rXh2qFrV0DltVJOUcJwznQ0NV2mlm@rt9FigQVejolfATGnrYRazrOndyDk82Ymk2nLHQku@RVNEimqqrVU9TaQA@nWTr0u7TCunlfXC7fxEwNpmtIaujBimrc/XbkSn/69XGvB1P4eAD8XEsWtO6/vNRpQOr2h7zQydAVdinpXqSy67h2RZdnrJAgjzfZrVnuEXg0xV9bEbDZ7p8O7xhyxJs3DLpLAiz8TicgFOy@75NbAft9mkTuPxa7GZXHQa8MlDvH6s//tz371z36Zfr9K939CPb9O3xooOxDoBDpHA6471Wqv0RAbnnjWQnsDWlSuWq6Wlc5FK7XTbLSfMzX30XmyoCdfMBwHVEyjlW41KX6Dkm0EyaO9kVg6N7hLI@4WePDA5ADvAFMssYo1MkdYY@xSOBhkgxMRUvOk0ZaQNapLTbVYaEs8VvMOVI6olSpip52QthdAd7R2QytoT9mdBr/YaNtnLuZG14phQYL8NpZlW/osbY24U6IRRmssw3zZcEGeKkKi2VTaJo0MjTCjd7aqW@Vqsaopncbmq7aMgRcFNU3zmZ84SURXjQXtMMRnImqZMbdX8ZqIqoWFDZitxL0hHNQVkAjoGfwfv7ToYlRdelEVa4FJ64isBu1D0yVt2BFzqhh1Nproh2sLfvSHK7Lic4tcAmcKcvXaYlV1R9OVwq3ioYYD7Q1XPN8CDBis1@123/a6wH4YRtfoGerUmBlzY2FMu7PuvDvtzXqM9xm2LL2nuwW37IZWWUroBXU7cRuLpGsVrYyfiNTLZb2i6SVVLxX1Uk4rF/RyRS/l9VIJAOolTa9U8pqmF0t6sawXi3qxAu4ahClCGB0hlAp6RRcS75pb7Dkna22WCa9W5sbrpSx3AiMZXLwlyZ0nhMQ/wNVQNZXtwNCXgwfwe2QEcRx/qiqwBPBwZ@13O813O9DjG5ldorbthhTkEl5y5047I11cNMFcqwX/3UZkrNHFTVC49kUms/uqAazNq0YzAyBfBSBliRFQudNg7V3yilILkgv8d9vAHUmZ3eZu3T2gW6Y@J7UB5O5KNu/cychgugMxG9vQt9OZzLYkbeGA2wyGHQjcbmTC8gCkdool826y6N5hUPif8gYhEujHxe5F46K5e3Gxuwv/XXpeBG9wvdi98qfX8toQZunfRtrTaiqNltIK6E8b7LLSQBdZaYGhAW8I19S1chtHPORf5PY/zr@cXT4jF8xyW4ZcC4kdtpNAPbZ6YkdIvH7/xf@Cd@v9F7@HvCiDn1kVEmdIKZQdlGQrXKCFB3MeO@wxvxww4x1a0QUdGo/R0eEPBxe7FOW1zKp8PSGllotpGYf0jjvooGocmb2GoCukFakoE7VyUexk1IXGErtisUQk9GeuXMlk8p@81iqlJJ8EQt0ur33ffxzL5TKfELim5VRJPW/wz5fwL039zLrrn/zMpktInFeYWQX8pBhHjJCAdpRQFElqCInG7hgP/@AyjIQS70n9M@nlvoRTNMaUFtl6fPqh/vCwXqk0UP4xt59R39m5twNPFf6HW1AK1hpA0Nag3hsDb90a6AWthZ@6SEjdN/h79BZ/7KiHv@dv8MeO3uLv@RR/7HEXf0dv8Lffxd/RGH933@Dv8Vv8vRzir/UVXVdr4vYZISajVtSL7blICKrBiNVofWXqLar03TZR29NAYA0msVJ6vpJOtL5iznvmZFoNZhvxJJbZm9aMeqXWrWtB0GAbOfrIlo978nEZKphcrGosjdOgeqXgehLueYQHOGT0iup6yR9/71vfStbrSSlJn9zKg5vUxUBdCgRWiJnnOcFPGUP@oLp9P1m7k/xKkyYYCpV2Ez3b4CEk6mxb3VZzdq6XU7tqFwwWy3ksN8qN1L5KgljOZLlFbsFyY1ftg8mEXw5MVm7AckOWc3IOBANfME07uSmaBvAawm8AgDz4WbidvqvmegwSspEVpa8Lqx2MmTvvtIQmSzLxtQmStKzKOblotfGDaE3x9euWstPWKmUmY7OWO83XrWRbbIn4kQytkmfdhbnVei0Cw5ETefNHF5bwfRDPawml1VI44gFdVJMXF53O4ZN7nY6CI2GLmY3MnQwQ@Dt36kDwg9deolHba1VpvAjHjISyu9dq6BKaixkYDTR0y3zJawkR3o0tKnn79elrEGhSpyjWnJ7A6zQ0fNqCR4cLPOStnH7ailnJoCinpzz0GggrhiUjE/@DPPgP9bf@cf0fv2Rplmq206mzi90UXWn8pdNnF2cXwbORTqUCS2oXfugAdoxydtFAIwU6A1MzlW6nLy64GzxT6V0OsAHJ7DYo7jLcGXK@UZqULn@k/n7fkHZwtfi3tF6LNWAkvB5LiK/JwVhu92m15rlcGghU8OEeXLw2zmlPRbpGX23d7jbV9p/8gD7OtJemQIV8rabuMG7R8lqtlg9tpXKtVg4t26lU5erVyO2pRZCG8vl0ulYDy14INgdWiNtk7zKszlrwbN@@zRMpa@fnIUw9X8zkcJtVrRamVIBkTd/ocWoNeD57@JS@bARUopBgSAxwQoQoQSpH30ZDOp4Uq@Lt26m@iUcu@nv76du3tUru/DxymUzASV1x6nT6ltfpoLt@fi52RNqkUymAPVc@P1dzlYyaTLte6gl@uBWSSkkqu6U1KNUK0GgtXwLvIAOF3d1ivtEo5sGlWE5C7dU4gYb8JsVkTUycUTHUconTL7GGzlBC6NAwPvpnFwmqS5YvpFNA/NLAOV4k8OchneTjU6GQruVzucTZhcgDq5UKD51m@WKqnKkEv/pWmjWAO@I/ZPH0TH6ntHMHmGX8@fN1F5LS2plZVy/qZ2YVp/ovajDC@y7wNqgZyLx9W68Aasq5WksI6G8dRiBksODREpLJDLt1W0B1SV6yWrtDdaqWCyyRrHFHKQl0nJUBt4q2U1DLiAzBGqCeL2ASBC6obbEtQaM3PoQK56W20BEEnyuUT@jDxfqsy4Z4sSHKkcxiNl3MZtyfnr1eFMjlV@AbWSkuiZqhixldfHpdL@i8fcLQ@@zR/sHhUVbblVhCu79/kNVevLybUNFaWNrJW0f788P9e09fQoRnjw73Xxx@9PCTw5fPwN1np8srGhbCwSEaJGKmNfZT9qnwuffWME3DnJlm53Q2O33DPresjgV1ac@gUO7QY77ZgbJMjGW5anD3LN/4/HPDm9DF3n//O@@//9@9/@3vvf/t77z/7V/98Re/@h24fwj39/j7e/@uUsDnj7/4F7/z/rd@Gxz/E9x/CPePfvzFr32T32T/I7j/S8ztj4I7Fo7fAsD6hR9/8cs/@PEXv/jrcP/r4P71q/cv/Wj9/avf3nxjvF/@nevDfO/fw/27HFYY9nu/xd3wfSX8b/Fwv/jr7//Vf@D/Pwl@aPzt9//qj/ARWP75r//Jf3n/rf@oaeU/@bfvv/3L77/9rfff/u77b/9T7f2v/Vs1F3/8zvtf/f2//IPf/cs/@B/p/0N6/u6H/N//@j//8//1z//3P/@D4P4R3P8BTD/68/8I/fRvfv/7@P/l3/@bP/w@/v/nf/M3v/8rf/ML/xMZfoMb/p9//e/4869@6T//9W9@9y9/9M2//pUf/fVv/P5f/h@/@H/92n/@q//@9/7qn30LHX/jR3/5h7/wF9/6zl98@1/@xbe@2PD8zrXPLz7A/Yt/AJcPz@eHwPmQcn1Zly9@qvz8XbCxTAXaCbTun3//az8HDfxfMfb@Oz/EI7Vwb/j/UFMpzA@57f8HBu1qmdEnBya4f@X9d76HKPofAEXwj/D13ciy4sMt311aAK2/uSbSz//4i3/5A7IlzGqDVpJw6C5r5cwOiDc7lUowfAeLTBDl51ahRQCClL6LFGrF77tI295//5vvf/BP33//N95//xdw8Jbylex@VlJvWKGDgIUPCIcBix8SDgN@Bul3MjRDJ2U@A9vWZ4Wy7jhO7bPPPhM65wqe3b5zzj6DH/ssvBj3wrPdgVfoh@542JuBe/P16zYu68bcFJUDVzT@Drxw1z2kJGm3MnuKqnEv81zZ5rFYDRz0st6KZV0ZDHaq8GPwqFZ3zrLSXgtYP4p6IZhhkdQA6pbCVCOr7@gGBFTyPByrOndy@UxpxzBAjs0g3AzxQDshR1bQ2TwTJDkPln7RHQLNd8g4Z3w@f07ec2FOK8TwLzFWZjpjDv/XBJYhdoku/MZtaCRDEC9cXSajUIBkMsvVAmIRGefSdrgLrZlTuvkKwxLM55k5yN5ggBQy4HUXZIB6PYMR6zyLYOWFaZQZZSWTqUO5MTaPk@2UEcT8LkGBmPXMc9bZqc95xAzCa4ToyAjo9FxUNTFTrt@DBOvzewxhIXAC@/p1vVGuzxsI7h3HTmaeuUt5QmD1zLzxDux1ggnxhMS9d5CVcj2TaZQxQSwkr55sh1dSgQpHZc@wTFAH8MajD3t3GLslqmWRL5RsIcJ4aHxmlqExIAQH/1ZmJygO/UMj3TuE8C1KKkiFcf894pH3ONuMAQCuJMmyzODGvQh77A54zzmoDCULrwyHkKEWQS0gcmA4m5QRMlS/GbJA@uB86llTk2lavgbiRo2hk9cT8OvAtLs9J2zPcWvlGQtY5FyN0ZTkhWBAmHxOF87OjeCEwrbBLsCpKGAInubOl74ws4is7e1tIdEQdfGpTFWjKMw7rtI5E9x6iYJTlYnFiojOJh26CcsK8WtUvu0kLl0mGQfMbmX4fefODrsFaKT30k1gUkZ3826CQ9nNZEQN4DfcjPBqB7GVyBCgc0Ge12mpNCNks4zJ9QT6sadPnwaZIIdXdSED3UjTVbTjit1sNktADFnOytls8JbpTQ5yYJDJN3jL24hIFhfXVBDi0fHdu3dQxbRxrfoQBGcW7GHT8mXyBAeuh8u2F@FRLC1fEfjcAlOLecZSVJlwpRmeOUpBq0wL/MADbxnhlUpq5XKSQgKy5dROuKmxqCI54Ye76Fg2K5RWrJCbuBUnCvlsNC7OR6eqeP5S5UI69Dx4yg6ePn58@ORo0m4zAT/KO5uanYnn9kzfT6Hf/pN7vOVplWI60WwiVo6qGpI34bCawxaYeXjv@cMXVcaxFFRQispRo3XtAC8VVUhMJp/uJoI9YCJ@WdUVX@CzukRFSqsA6U0nGkKiZ6I8BS0N/3DXhMf@8K47Z6lcVhSzahHl2zSuz0I@ftadMdT7zZWEQY/GEzPy7i5hQGicSbHlIHRosOeawA2SSgamV8qhocQNaqmIAfg@S6YLjReHRwD66ClTtZwsND5jcxmzJl0IDbtum85wOtrGDYtiKyfGSr/dzGXxp@k6PNV8MasWSu2tLftMwoRa1B7OcOfpBVjPJCzwV@FiwlcF9lVwgku6YALuJ2XB9PrDp7VgRyUq40zxbZWiWoD@mhZwiSCAJ0ziFxCgxKU1NiGx9Y1vTFmjcfjknvTwPs4TzEcs3FYoWX15JFOb6M88k3yHjPWtTyz8vq7ct/yJbSygFwJCEhcXFwOA9PA@0xoaWXmMPj4veuTSBfPF3BCAVg6ExO1wPkRIONVq/Z2aLwnP96vVd7qmCeAg7Ci4j3ELWg9tAtlR@K/mQ6K6XlZ2hIQqivDSdV2gts@Eqikw2vPzLlevSwFlzau05UfAbzgZ8/py8T4IO7@1DKvneFj0AQ82nHosF/qVuF9gC4kxoBG3OeKWdaEWEIPc7ds6Tvzo@VxUTEZIYBdQYdt6XsdKADdwbSfypWBRShTFdkKwzSnr18GcaMGjxvuhmhAZ2pBO6eWckGgmoFcKzXaz/v/9r90U2vN/vH9AS7NZF@ZA3OJ34Ixh6M1WfoLw2H26/D99Oo5br/2Pn7qPn7pjF/4wVD1GylNb/mu1Fev1/4DoIXGpwVgkTPGoUw5@@VxB@Ed/Qc@mJs2XQ3cDdeEN2qzbVCv59iF0mSZr74aaxBsQepcfgmaowq0uYoGVqRUcjG74pj2Q8ZRfXdydNPScJu4G3yxphBEb/Xrf7c1wW1WtL1uOY3p45JpHyOfFmuug9t96uOYIY036TBjWT0ktjGDWhzIqlPMcwxb6ctftL2R/urDxvJztevUkCDvJ0GMJ3QQuGCd893Q9X4UiyRN3sidohVKmqeaAvcBbLWe17Ja5VypV@3LPNg1vr1AtlLN9PIoXrAjvFXLVofzZ40cPptPJc5PO5@3lKxABVbCissS9crVQgBYripkmJdNu5toyH3SkrS0g06bRl@CNC8a@pJXbELlvefV6Mrmnq5qkVvVc@UJYIg5wPlIb@Vx@V4E3SGYKLkTDgAg4RSSru8oEqw@MEMQAYxeMhV2lC0YLjJVdxQLjrKGruV1lxmsRcdYQMDMZxFUWazI7Us@CkaLquI55IVSzRtY6I9RWB4PBxc5ZZmkRjDOJ2wDpF5KR7Z5F1poUC1dls6xkLT3BxRhAHZ4F6@tVUSuUxVqztrSXimKtfSHcGZt9y8Czfq3c2dVYRRi/OdQEJNRiwkXVc91ptWsOXM9cBtTVYhiQZ@hqgLx4ESXXymGKZ1eTK8YCzc@uQskXxIsoVpgt4eICKpPjG3rbq1dCYuf5J3qjAQ3jLF/S8oV8QdOLxUJJA56jki8WylCpuWKuoGnQC/OVcqV0Ab1AUd4l6EO77OAs7B1V@tRQyqhyXdnNNku/e2LZZ2Vd4v04la7BMJZ4JyRuPf9EazQ2T1akgEf7RJMadb1QAZOOJk2nQU/TJE2XdFVSdfzfYNDw/@HhNfhr@IRYuiYcoQa9J8A6AWfosEeoiWvqsiMXv8U4ZHfN3oYQByODjiIceK7v/x3C3DWcY@51z@Jq6yOvBwZ@kNYfW9PRhhAvJ2NUvmd6/2AQDsddyCBSTx7gLjw823XXBSixl882lPJx9KEYQAb/UgwEf/7wowdHsffR4f7BA6HI7j59cu/SqxAEKrBHh/ePImuJ@4ZRCxGInz189OiyNXjln758Ppi5Ht7C/acv88tH5IQn3YU8XKuBImcCEjzQSnIIsJBsC8Sw0KAKeD7qdr7CbgfGQnFpzKHxU36M3/Kj8zpco0NVOArP9hukBqRrsh7XsYhTS6T/OJAU1VJFECbMcU9ZKcf6rm0bHnMHgy1wHBl4TtlE@ce2sSVi0qeuZ/dPrb65BTwNpFEBMXJAmRAeAJDxrEfqe4B7RW36MAg6DJdsu/bMZLMJ2@gIL3RCo2cNRzBkn7phAKFrGAzuL3tBfDN@Ta93mPI0yO2Kj301uJAQKomyKB6I4gNjatQ8s/QqV60@82Do9odm43AOzRU6j@EtsuWsLk7F@6zqvNrRhrjyZ7sTlFb9SXNnBqz51haI3H/1mz/82z/@Fa2VO8jhlOXjR3ltAdyFqtS69Xcg@4@7541XbC/v3mEMOXkU/OROomNWge6h6MNQtGEkvQQSjkyCslYpF8oVXStny5VyvqAWC4WsqmXVUrlUARg5tawWy4WKmi3nK8DX5CvgWwCJlctHSigQKTtVAOv07Fnf3CVZWx6BUM1X8dnblJFmCSOyz5hoQhxRwHmQKamF2LHqMHoyNcf0EgOIBuuxxP37B7n790XxLlpwE9NBThT7aCmUc7nSXVE0yeegjDya6PI4ZVRjLE65JZe7C7Uw4wDwC0CiOELLYRGnpUXRQsvB/v37mM4ALRrGh2DH3Idb7NBSgmAOWkBqIwBvImgQbJ@nk6eMHqIFk0Sf@9znAPxE8aMwO@jznAfjAB6EJd3fF8WH3LK/jz4HVOwCz@jX0LJPlyh6YIHeIYpDMAw96Jei2AUj9hFR7IGptzDAbQwm/EiMMzVEccHRgwgSxTmFNnrHotgJ3TGZT4LcFBC7VbKovNR3yFLBnyhqYaYxmB5ZdFHMR5Y8lO3Bg0@M0bRvDvm18Pi7ByV98EA3rPns8H73o4@6w2HXW@wffvQcvQ4OHgArsph53WE3iNjtwOVCrIMHmnE8Xly@oNQPO52qYa/1@lqnkzecS16dRcfEHEKsN5Cz4BpiQuPOAXgdPOjcMdbtxiCAHSQPY3h38bo7hvddo8u9wou86D3vdsUaNn9FaaUElEBwYwV2x2Mgt052bPQ8t4b2eZ3lssjVLJrFXLtGHmwMkkSudoH@gxQ@DZxrTJ8tmvN6rl2f10vB9sdBSmzNtYIlZrfGe2qlUN0y9lQtn5lXUTONO0iypKTusZR6e@ctSz1J72kgVWyJrb09SWyq7b1i6RVSoCo@9jS1XM3nNJbmVr1UhTi5ZI4xfKSbpfZeqVBdRi6VMoaiVUsl4NwAP1MY/7s44ddhqdSpaRyn05h1mlSC8lDB2YIKbdUGqXl2XueZZIt0bV5Xa/xLCSx3CVoq1cfP8sx6qI2dcaBDADjfy1VxK09KVCtlEfKgKKl0OqKBCpiWU3Sffv3o@OjoM2ISG8GM1zPPRGJWC6wfPTiQHz4NbfhJHfk@Mq@uJx8gEVvx4Vxs6HQEIon8AIZdEBhDNzwQ7Lm2fEibWIEDDj1CrX5yoN5ePnqwAufFyD3lKaM@lRrpSHZ6JsMvDll9ZtQbYDL6LEW5Ykb6lAb8TqNR79THpHIEihjG@hqjz/EswTz0ed4jLS8U/QwPyQYenXruAgadeWIOcDp1Jqmvx27/tZbp1fr4oaG79bsYudaBd7dm1k3Pcz0RpD2xNthz6jPHNwbmM9ND/UUPn24D@4EnZ1MDZqa3WesQQx@g1HIhNTzmLHP2ZDZOGVKjm151wonfyAGRk/p6WOgzOszdqYviRW1QZ6lXEPQN2L1tlurLd9N7@Rrg6S7rpMEp93rwesA0VszXSDhJISzoWYQfLLfB0vXG1@DFYR9Xq5CboKKPASomBoCtPnlA6Il1UevVbZaS2JylCUn52rDexOjn@NiVYHSXpOZ5W2hI0qdCA7pvbZEw6v6sS9@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@Ei7OLXZDevyK8wNPVu9or/JVePd5/ir@vgFMFrOVXj18@ffn0vsAU2kENjGRtqybXOjWwSHLjjpCoMgaktBVokFO2GPuye7Mzu41X/N3CQz0AV6BPWTRZm/ZMmhaKeuwT1E6yx5JQCMMbNzVNbze1EoyFQE7DoJqm1iAXnQQeG5IbUBvzM8jfbqaBB3u/xhYLIyOF8wO3q41hZjunLRInHbFY0fm51IaaO2Zbyds7DNgbiSVOjrca2k4m@ayqZ5L3kno@cZJqbTcy6iKpsJ2MthjgZg/cNKAkIZxm7tzSd5IvM9XyMFtVM/jU4FlNMmkrcaeTvZOu@ALVCUtcmrDYr@8Pn@/XQttBo6wtggPJiVcdsVwKstjaBpRpmVersRswAL/CVRbc1pmsJRNnSZZIXiQvmsm2kLhDx541fuyZJaKDz7jdIlg31PNFlk5U0oGtVEn4qWjR7ivJO4kkro1Vff9dglpVeJb0a681aNAJxw0dQAbEyTcYcAsFXBVKKK8n/je0sv744VPnnnffFBKtrfMtF5fzwulmuN45H3@dsQmgOMla9cS8ng/ObqiNhqTuaqjoscSqMKYM1KKUO2/wXtMgj6IGPu9/7tfz890y2LWcCnZNK2S0RkPdAWYlMXn/xe@hyq6zw0/2H7EkruP87R//QCv97R//G9odmrygtR1NLyUgJBrVYilxdjY5O7uAi/sVEu3ElU0xbcCPohqV0o4MpVHKBhg6SoLjEZiqkppO@FIi2BNcLEiplKpo6R29nEuDz3mgki@l5cpgDddGyUksFsR04vC5VdDUO7t7ULI9Pa/VtqAu1egIO4t@u6ZfgcopP359zhhYeo3@cGhpZFIUVn0n7b5j0i57h8uS76Qt9rrewE09Kh58D1fidvBALS5sJxsZZSfJQBhjjeZF7aKdobU8kmxf7TitS3hobeFprVWnHQd@5o5PP9MkKzn4YA1t5s7nvpjaSStKv08qInGpVJIaCd5DOiYrNKCp7CiQy51wIY7/JKmVfv9zv6Zpxb/9418675x3PtNAkK1UiqqW@MlPdmfOzDf7jZ9AxGsUNIXCKLGgqEkJDZEQy7iSVSuIFRnkHsjPMwcZdh4@FGlRiGXA3VhDx@yTSCucIEdGNdrhOkL7KQq2g/pbssTwk06@dE0QQmaYM/TesJclGGwHdcI322nhTPgqesGAz0AoqAlfXYIChzEM8W6v49szb0Kn3FIUT21n2W2IAil8FfWvbpHemWC0kIBqKjtXo/Is@4Q14t7Y2PR91OYKA53wVYgSfDjDXrCJgSqSMKTlwPAkYxDKJ3n0m5B2G9K2eYQOuaao9DxAlvHc8UgO8PnCV4FhISxYwMcwaxcC1ICcfBUQAGVIBYCtNttlepqdWZlMbakq9oJBpeOpLyNUzyJgNITWR3VAYeQahgMnkC/wU@3YLoIaBjYy5hgC4TD4dpU6SCgYnWzIGpL@pA8GBbBIV2GKisZu317mql63@mlGJUL4x9YE5@OoHpz1eQVgoah3q18VswyV8NZC16jZAcYzlF1odRLXvluLRWUiWi8EAf4f3GixRV6qKvKoYQGC@uK9ogcog8iIdl6HPbZbZ6pWSrMo8z3Ie48yRUoyIvm1Nb8la5@FnheQw58kwg8hArE6is9xBu32sn4eBuz8DL9Ch1oaOTEI9OpwPYxI9B5Ow9hRLCiKZVPogeWBKEVba0IVsCldTWO0pcpcygcdeNHyDM@dFNL4olgYmsHbQFWmQTpbpIKt50KF@hPXId2npJsNj/5AiwAaFaiN5NmeOaf41dKgbihyPEc@qYzElo85Jl2uLiq5ori4VaXrgdAd4ibLzKHMeuM@0yosRQ2N1Fs6Ebg0RaIMd4EjRxx3bXMMWXphmnTW1K8qyhCYtFmXdHw@tqBdje5bMPI4vnKPI1g5tY4t5Qg/HyC5AzySyjUmJZCvw@7H97oE@jRt1z1mtnVs8qnr1Iq@KZ@BTAJsdRYwu7wBsVXcjKXpWZwpUbM8FNwleJW4sZyNxd1KLdJX37q6lepgjZ7TCGZBrdjmieHE8EvXuRAI4/7CDzXWkd41sMsRyTUDXVX1JGqhiZSwCYHuvTqpfZNxSWSSEhNiqLMOjcLEM08YitUCjjFANHuh9ifsxVDar9IAQH0Pehaqsp16VdRZBjnx@qkedL2AwDvsFtM1AQNyhYKB8j@AgVVfX4UOfhAVy@FP@1AxMq0DIF2B3jnugx9qywmaH8YPWzeaSc3wsnmzrQAcDjqUVp3xbhFaCjEL9g5sz1T0LfAsQg7X5GQrJWYAbEZMixx0FP9ydN7aBaIlVXYVUpYhhADVAIVYBQNJDuoqjX1eVACPu4bPv0EVKLo9PT2VSfvyzLNk08dPbvquY9jKZGgBJ@wqU3M8UUwfuq5n9ZRJCHdpkviXduXJaLI3R362Xrm94G9BGPj1YNNaKjnwkzg4nuAXJYdj0tSIKhJ9alD3LfoabS8V7KHj7U9rZ8/C9lfF9ieVkxcIhDEEM88usr0sAMt2e8fZwWm/FnicUIcE4FCLZuiIOtG90DL2Q5M1GUQh3CnS0cirax/TkjFAEvmU8jJpXsIw5CK0BvaJhdtUHfOU7XuesUiRfxpDYwNOLYjtYQsY9skHjPh9jjOuoNuaNxftlejzKDoMatEuDA/VMApn1wPl2trRf8795@A/5/7zZaJhss15m7Nk6HSBxcFWj/ttw5AIZhGGueCazZc@BBn4cKZyEBhyseJ2AXevTrFDfHMb1GM9bBjQJiaAcDOlNF@1mq2245unO@2MMoTGLhIioMYBdLNNOD3tR2bEvn1iT1x/xclBpc0wKgX5RqfeKGgNvK1gGaMKoobB8WWhnt3hONguwhmCoMAAAfkw8ETWYH@astK16PMA5AkNpykuccwz1gwy0ybuK/AK3IBd4qjniI0DascAoXtUJMgm@LCw5/APLIfU4VPPhTBh2P@3u29bbyNH0rwWnwKm5GKmlTzJtmxTpsqURNnssiWPJNvtlVWsFJmUssxTMakDy3Z/s3uxL7B7v4@wrzLvMFf7FL3xRwCZSB4kuapner@tbouZCSAQCAQCASAQkeeYsD34e8yd5IiSU0NFZM0Gd5KFVT5v0CSyQ12tTjfFpFNXHE8lWc38pvvfRv/ed6PfoXExH3tmWJkwNjL2UIGFLqkQergwVdVm1epXwqD4wO8GI5q56qKf6tmaqnlQNMsMqQdNiK7CcevcsTq/5Ur/8NXnbD9biVlhUq1SEydVGZYyLgxJheBxsUgXmxhG0OVFgBCM0txigS52bRe7rlZFcKjrBcWuLCSvGclrKSK5rxcgeaKL0eqpYaYXdM8JaacwIc4SvLJMo6QGDbMq8i8DnNL/Cl@0OLfQdSYyh7lA8xBUbPBZ62Ru7ccW0pbQmgIARpwBQFqIf9EdVzLTAq@cj99iGSWkNDJK3jQbiKwgBmMRvCH@2p2YyXgNTAp/dpXnARq72dXjTLbMe8/4X0n@ZT3z0fwrz34spXOW0x9L3tT//kM@noCy1gC1tI9y6REEMlYy7/ra0bGtcyyr2gUtcEirO70aKGeOsk3fixe6aPG0Ozgt9nxY2yCCu3wtDCeuWT/g9Ea9GA7G/njw6FFFFk0hs928@mXNEJ71Bwj8aMVsIF2vPQiifm5MndoanPXDKPAU3Ol@DvSyI9BRZDK2nqwfB1Emow2/ZBkL0MJXUHWbzbAfjptNB9aXbiW@SsDGmGDPXC6D9S89WeVJPGmg@0NncPpr0Bq7t8NEABJd7ChsfXb2hzoRjlpqimRYi/R/Sj0nDUZFg2TlyMENoEqfjh0O93M@6A3OSOu7iArYgc1MgW8ksIGQPxwyLp7ysaStWGFoeJQ4Lc93ddGfvruo@mnN8d24/FoaQIoYnhpN0xiUHc2prrmwOilm6jv8fnwPbXwPb8aXV@HTOMvSvCqJ31f1QyeBQBkTNB7ejgaaTnKrPYNOCpX4M/QqKXBnFNtszdYGpjXKWtPZCx3iDy9@i@gtRvz9Ivrf3IGmeP2u3efTsFeHE5I3PVhWi5OlyBzCOpS94UL2zFYXs/bOHeuivAiTvgsVgtRYFlx9@GWngYnAalEcW8gAvoXnYUA2w/dsVVaVxDk4jS499XltcRftNNtB158EbUfn9Cy4psUHtGBjeXW3hkPQsdAbyFrPobnLjVNpGgfRJVNlAcv43qXrLmYryRLG3MM75YxhYzH9kD4jmrHFV5XdaloH5HLL2I69DLH9iYByEvqjK4FatRyV@Ud6Eo5bbicI0UFmz7KXVOveJD4PnLhJd5gR4ryFdJPhmd9AhEe12T78PhLd3lLqXKtQ1fRyJh30an6Phzf1uMUVhifluOluLHkb092Z5yxWE2CJCNv@vilkBjIsR1otx4YoX27ssUF/RibgG@/T9RfMKs05AjUuyZJuHPJym/ULN4OVcYN@seH0nn4B8CwYN4WhTNuwp6VjnytO6flDS2vRX0hJJygWFYXkGg0rV8Y8U/Yv3@I6WwvrbM3U2UrVGY@AdJVWpkwrVaXuBXTPTV3QDTrjBdIZSVg7089NYpv@6w/8EXYrvuTCXCX0VO4yVyGBnAtylbpDQjnXzlV2@CHKVQ754XOu8hM9JGMr9zVXMcMCGUb0yg8v8F2LcLy3cpVtx/2WGfufg8jUW8hV4j6lPD/KK1OESIF2k9aII7b@QDdzPApoYmOl0lPgmMjD8on3YTz@V6L/Sxg7DnCFROxxPuDMalWVU5OGNWNIPTRtmAAqc0ZyRc/m9f1dtryKs6CaVVrj2WUYPKnhy7m0MBLEkMonGvRLCEJuVuZjpKyZ7I7o6NqJQ7mT0/VLQFPWB9oOpx9T5pOkEo5dqMub/kqDkA68G54ovAjPGXRMdYwRzmTdOWiBqL/kbmgU@jqNi@59u4d4rzudibDNmyzSSwzWkumkw/HhHIeEHQzTTMKpuBMQ2mV4U04GJbh3qhhLBT0yFyTzZ90yCAZ78Ls3NccqB9RSIgiJx6UTGWXxvMCyGEmJrLM0VRl8hIIlc2iEB63PHBdyRz9yPhE3Hs8Vi6YhU1aqZMmVFpNUuABHdBf@WGqPF691uKf7vuWrKXmNvRYHAKyScS0iXwffob8PRH83CrUhwlQF8xTr@VPprHp94yw7hXk3qXa2A5HoqR13rnIU15CQnFYHlmZ@E6/NqPgw@RAlXyqNoU9p@4Zs8ZrgFrpNry0EFrSE0WX64@c1@vh5bTGhZjWS7mXBKC0F1KThSMNjTJOm3YyrNHxeFyOF97f97nd38CjdwXbnAR43YDRFchnlo4s@W7kkY5vEtnyBSC1XlAhyPi6Nuzn5SOKej27jY1v6sN882Nnfe/2RJt0nT564eo6eJPhh1GKvNZ7HBTKbccfzwZxly5qH4G047MZ2fHQ@GI3vfepnZ2SJCGtSBuCPxbCfHuOulmWWPJ8au1RO8loU1bA@J8PAT0klqDo@puxQ03VMBAnGzgNfAzHqLdHb49Way2HKms2@34M9P6avZhPGS82mnsXQNeZE3P378r3iRTTiaNUSY@8qk2EXKmpnX314VTtSR6/qavfd9k/q4/479aG2dwSvF2/fbb1ubCv6V987rKtMygQP8UixoCS67gStgMNor5VKjxRD3h4MJyJ3nG1Xvh/6PfVq0ApwTPU88nsvzuWl0A/Gm1KqTsvRCfYwQ44/2wvHsLfggKm0jIVy0@Z7jLh5oCjvKa1pe1jz9gbtsBNS3gzWvsMwiMzVN9UNqQdJ3prL4p4oSYiNyqZDHPMYFlhXVNyn/Di7ITC@2F@BxMghwVTbBaUJF//33RQ8qh@8OVRwtbK9v7fTOGrs7x2q3f0Den37sbH3kujZODw6aGy9QxJnfLO/09htbNf4gyBQKij4QPn1IhrfiEIB2Zkqrc84@S4Mqfvjt/SuNzR4deXzjc5I5S76kD6h3w1/D9q5jcxFBPUFt0j5qEA5K7WDl@9pzlfBbzjhNEfBbH@QfRdxvN6VknrOtdFg2aTxtqGHK017@bLL5xG9iULIrmCDHZ44/OwpA5yNeNphoLLbsFHB3rf4ReGxbEBTRfcINkAZg5Wq4lB7uZz3nEFuUm2t7gAufqU2MSLULyj6wpiabGSYYtpWBkBxs6LRx35QeSP@QHxPH9Z0teORZFAP4w@SQT2SD1BFG7AdUY91jovx/gXEs1qXD7/2hrt8LKyexB@2fF7FPtU4Sb9xl/oqDlUKLzFdDqgouzwc9Fn8A6FIxPkRbLDblYERSJhbkolylMi2bZQzS8Kmg6MGbfYm4eORStwAOyG/M46UU3UL6gjGQUE/lFCWZ12/LyZQiekO8556Cs9hVX1hPIxDQPJdleGAGRDhZ9N4xOV2tFYY3LUcldyaqdHXNpIchtmYoN2GwNYMAn8EDAHKp1Y6LZ6p@JItwAw6mpWdaEAciX3bv9n5iZ3bF60gVUBbbTm/hr//7moie6l1krFTZOyoi34PRqRW8lFmZzCiMc5ilYPmQQq2zgfDcSh96KRbwCdOPM1RbkxsVNsv1c1UbaDDdI39Qd@q9JS4eEGtp8SUd6mVOV7OzmPxlURTJ86nSVjs7oCOfzq4DKyzMw@HSFcBtl9IEeazcmx@TsaMieifmUR2/E0hCPPT6ubO1qf8337xEIlZxIIEQjdGh/hHjIm6aHjwOR8bLI6gd@mRZiJoRhenKK1t8LS0xCg3wGgdeB7Suu5FcyNOE3Pj2e@4xzP9nT9@/VqVUnlIJpHIF9G5k0g3Tx2bKj0uc6K0CYglOwlZkvWO@eIxzFhev8DdHfTCBlGkDzmCdftUfEotQkzrTi86JFl0mHDd3TF8V22yRYVRJMWThN0fxZ@drerqpltMDEqURU7HiGjPQC67rmWWwvPVDLidm8GR/L47uKc3YifTw3dB27kR2nfhll9dDEumJQvW3cH@7QawMrn9IbDUdm8xYJkkZ6HFnB4zp7eyHFvT3lzjLzN9x2OPwGDuxQ5KDNSq7aLPR9TGVb4jBVwbTKIQHR7t1A8OVFbWJ1SW5B6WDG0tBgH7nnqbWNuGfRZ2hVhpihfLsfJkvqQs2sx/Nw3mucRbICq0DuJpesTCIr6HQwu6a5F6emZhFYKt71kgGsqlsftiZFB0rAF/ozUgIZt0mtXAzNxmLsvkE0a2Ebimmye6sW3DzxbWMncj@PZoYgOybYL8M9wsmd9/H0Q/rph6RMGCByc0uE2aNM03tE44pIqHlLFQSPfgDd1iuhRG9qJgLxvawfCrlNaw/zxDMSOJEi66sCXWtXKsURP9eMWoOWyQiGnAh6WnThSLZkowIp6/PLc71E0mPSc9BZGSiXDML2yuoOIn3/QUxtSI58lqrJDbY22FsTk2WJ5gd1bD3lic6T5sodenxcN0VSRtb6wq/4@pSmaJVE2G5nMbYxIJ8vrjxw9vgz3dClM8/2dhyxwyLT/HvSGt7xOQ0STi7X3i3MaeZ9ITBriBdGJabwbMVEFSdebMKam282Rk40e4yL4QIYNAE4hwPV2rq66ncJsPXWYkGzpnmWmDNYTjhsqomaH@t5urg0C@tb5731@fDDZkgungN1jlvxmMoiC5lWf5lrE@4RJ@@lswGvU5m9xn6gGKw9eYbrxsx7ftxOBVWoVEPm@zW9LRt5PE7NYzew1cCW8vFhDUHrt7G9Pbe/nyht3U3cbrunrAflU7qb3I7CjrWrLnXti/CQGWwbwvgemD7/Ddjyr0j3DwDEgiE9/mc5g27q24MUVIaz7m@GHaLFTL1vJ073eilt@HNxIvez9SWe8HKsi7sPX9XXfeznppI1WekIuGfYdKedl8IctF6Rs2dAEpDUJ6E9@tCQs3NYylJK7XnA1gH4WDreBads/YctIvlp@W1p9luHV9b@z1jp@deA9a1ayiydfv96KL0VX789ng/LKjumr46@l1a/L7b0o9fgQv7WrtB/HCXV6vFtn18BMFB@7PSsy5GsEf2aM4gqwXJPq0UjmVrMM37imXH3jRXMENiSkuVQ96hgtxxW5c7R2vn1T71dJG77h/soFLfuPV6ni1vOrgww80i5KMkZP54/EJ5lR71zXoXyq4i@XYxvpqiOKrIfTljT8KB69rey9Tu3FQALAFpm29eUNdAtovwZoNd08K/eDK0dtkngLHZqAgZZb4VlAZ1915PxnbMe2QMKNe8Uibja7578TNLJUKF8PxgFOMb0mwlvoafs0smWtMJd5RoCzHofFAifsFBCfJ4@BgSL5OxIo6XxZ1rYy7k64F4hglWRxmP2WzuFMIRPVdruOTTFQI/NY5kOiSWv2Vi@FuMt6I1aIC7@LBlMMf8YWJ0gkecQBCP0M@bUAVrLlHfO0jQ83HexkP8oX3qMZ8T4YN5DOsKSIF5t/qC99v4vLPiQBC@CXRuQp6i1NrXqRIyt1B3lyAJ7b0wh/HDLhWKZ2yhMYCttRXTYCzpTjTCNVqMtH3pSuQU2hF/@kW5Mv8NtOMOL8r2ZkkfE6t3yLQkruUkzbx002KOVaxvClmMlukWLqVGtjpouXRm4CG1URtB90uIS20WErIgUe@36vrX43rj45R50mMvKTnZ9LzqfSCpAtSSa4CTfBJpoqdKbv8Jcn3TWWTbN5MXVXFykuBerpVIJUkybtxU96oMB40wyTzZtyVwpVxwvNUQt5K@XlO70vKvVSZmMHj9GNJ1/y9pns@xjKV90W6fvxmdAcFbDyrbU2muLTQD7s/yqQVp4DNskRNpaQ4B15VZlBV9R1MLU5Ig8M@Pw/bzWoCZbVsJA6Pmezm8xfZglYyfnSm0ZBbjDMDa84YsajEda4y4a75wiLVw8n3LBAME4ymzMjdNIUnuvDEAotc90y1cgtyZoBT06aHeBX3Ir/ijxnsaeRMvuX5iUuC@bU0Xm43pwnEQvdedj6Z0tIE10Xko27UDbNIUvdkGuJ8IbFn7QLHdQZyB7uDbfB7sZywBYWRFDN0j1M0pZMMZcO@i7oQid8yfy8@yLz0SccedoNrVcMyw@dbWJnUBfdxEI0jOKBi1zjRxXDYxakjK3xXfIVax4JYe4zjlgSiNbMXMg1Y9kh@D0/6QjoVKqh9QL6CgUiSEF2cneEyGW7ADq4gWrHjEo4LmVp/IhsaNGYersk180DB@QYL4G54ZiMhPSejB5SOhn4rKGRIR4tI@8lIUzuhjlfM@@m4NwI/ZzSlVTKZf7kIW5@3X@I890m59LBskexSHweXCg8fJResiEgmYQ2eCx@XH2Uy1tlwS86G8wDoqdeY6N8TbwaXQb8fZGo0Y3DGiJTWKBhdBu1CJnMQxIfAgAtWxskk7mEPLkYt2dwhpcsnZsQt4ciT4zDiMPxifpbj4haflXkZHFolp83U1ZdhGwQ0N046A5wO84EF3AQIPVCoF4yJKA9clUaJz541Lqy79LARRdSAnxPrbCImQ38wDlvUM7yTlekSKDkGSSrrt6cwofpaXR@XgwvzEMD1mIQCBgFzlHQTDhl9aP5dOCjdMHPG7pueKZL0G/BYoeEejEKSvgmBuVe4mIU7dfDRq8ahOtzfPfpQO6gren57sP@@sVPfUVsf@YwbB@XsJli92n9N0iU@TZdT8336kK0dUsksJ2Rqex9V/a9vD@qHh2r/QDXevH3dIGgE/qC2d9SoH3qqsbf9@t0On74TBLW3f6ReN940jijb0b7HtZpimaSc2t9Vb@oH26/otbbVeN04@sg17jaO9lAZTvVr6m3t4Kix/e517UC9fXfwdv@wrtCwzE7jcPt1rfGmvlOg@qlOVX9f3ztSh69qr19PNXT/w179QLGRgNXKrTphWduiJSxq4nbuNA7q20doUPK0TcQjBF976vBtfbuBh/pf69Sc2sFHTwM9rP/LO8pEiWqn9qb2khqXcW6hCvXL9ruDOtwmgRKH77YOjxpH747q6uX@/g7T@rB@8L6xXT/cUJnX@4dMsHeHdY/qOKpx1QSDqEXp9Lz17rDBdGvsHdGc8e4t7B1c6uQPRBjCskZFd5jAMINAa4lI@wcfARV04A7w1IdXdfp@AJoytWqgAiwqto/sbFQhEfHIbqbaq7983XhZ39uuI3kfYD40DusudVjjEBkaMMj4SKxDlb7jVqOfCC95JGbNGM71uDtVY1fVdt43gLnOTRxw2NDcwmTbfqVpXoCPYGsTJRxgz8Dv2RsrndlPlwHcYM7uyMzfo4k9Jm3v79RpRtZOrrJJwjuadZ5OuVKy02imiRPpNeWyph2cXpw1w35ngDumcTHZ@OhFZx5CbrmIGPQpc0PEO72/wgWWl5vN97UmLXQPm03Xu0vJFBq3ldDb4DflcnUbEVECK29s/FQqQvfnKUJt/qAPOtlQDwcQyCnU/0FM3/xe4KpisR3oYri8D8Bm6yiSY5NzHKWQaOTLjgh1lFTJOxP8Hmp24IKOAV9oNbFPCstIzjSI6E//a/Iik4P1gaSzbHcVi1jEMhrh74GpRiphlwj8R3skCDtcZSEKgs9nTsmuDmv@wtlg0HZc15ThvGNaB5457i3FT4OzqeL56fKMLB8767gJkVl3swoTnz9rkindL4URt8zBn@aYf1yDjfh8wK4pV8Wb1XrT0vlBisMiyVPatQWuV3AnQ@d7U/tr4wNWc6W1RxtT31/F32VswV4QLnNpwjvmcif88@pEMtAAY18cRJJQe8goFq0yxt4kznxFGc@R6Spsw/KH5urzgOd1Igkpshd@164Ts/EovLaxJzn88qD2Zuvd7i6JTmD76OnjJ@sbmdjt1l89@f2IetinLXsdG9I8TnoaJ1mjZJsUHx4plofxhP2ZgYtFZIR7edNp/BF@HmK7jbQlEwQZmhsh7lcfJnrZAHTIKnbAcS9j@HXuyNQM4KSa6qI1Pf@aVXyfdCXmAW3M0p1wr13jD2DHw98M8bhBmoE0i7GXX@JcWl2w3MvuGlNRXtyw4x5kKWQNH4sbt5gGvNXF9rO4XctvmretXozElBHjlbudSxIS96axUMauoi8j@y37GdEbwOw9jL78VfMbPX7UDu7Y3Z0fjWvjQyLjblwS@9TJZrRu9LGGfIJwH3CqZmp6rrDL72qkeOzp7eTYMYg1GhgVhLqBjW8a8EbsR2S6SraAfZFz1RfhVDjvAJwNzbH6nTh3XnM0lA3jP0S/G68USmDFTk6EaldxHRmT5WPsx8KQM0WmP0UPhv9PpMkc@M9pxUnQE2pZTgDvREmGKrSi5SsTJbwyBw3W6UZCTfvTxwTMN7tjzuOG6dOba7lfQyTQvTMxHz6y28OOM4cAYHJsbNjjNzZJO/dp6fQi6@riOCfpt3pDR@m5wkwVM3Dz6yceq12eOVvBi6tc2WuyKnxNRdULWbid8qinJdPUUl7dj7ICzjX@P4oPeAMkHvDMpeditTrNWSU9yowc0K6WrAmnHXtMIrX028JTuwfKcpGZkv365MsQikBvAp/ZdnLck4ES89y0x0WeidURe8GD53IskzH5aJd1p2yI2Q0A536bN0MQGmV8hQmiK9DZVV8CTTn32VAElSRWh4mfQYhbt0Ck5Wn1KsaedybBoTH27/riNj@QXS2ToyAOPjSG9nX5gnrjTwjl7t2aLSxWfHA48GC7iMpkW0KXRxiY1mAwItXRR7sJRy@cuAX1QW86BP3oYqT9F9J8Fo70joRR@qkaqE2yeudpRrzVM2pROMZthXaB@YOb1AtgISruSa7z68oh5jU8umk2HcPr1bJynicpz4km7JaUifhcrSMCLucSgmqXoQFTMIzixQXbbHI9OHeIh9/VYPQZcz9UoH47aMeeSS2QvBcondTos4/H1liaPhxEvKNBXYEdkJgSZdlIiw1VaY5@otlJ2zVlE@@Y8F3KLfn@emImNdZSVFHCuLp2Yr71PHUmqLSmXYPGzkLLa48ZlXkLrm8LF2PsLTR9bK2yn/qxSKmIElG9b1RHPIncjJ8@4klv8lfvRxg99AVn3FoFBcLQWXGuOivnGD/YFHwIg1Hb3hMlTabtD7H9xkufQZ950Wwdard/LX8cBRNaAbSK4XWRYTSdvwzO@83tQdc/CwehT@s0uJq/FomHxwk/osPORoOriCMcSahNK1N7kjyLfxlxw4b3@Fxyw3LNFY2DoWObKYxHk9q5uIngnXMYASbBeJm/h9M@0uIyjx4nhTLp@6dsj1d2NxaWfVieV1hO9AFAC7jNKQsKuUM65otJ1uXTjZkMpzdlsHA8VXnluwss9lIYPyMS8TFMCmODzIxZgt0IrMwWYnzcvvba7INwBEdLwU6AUDyRw589H9HVSYr8CEuBiio/LVlF5RTlGn4I8TBZTO61J/9k7AmBP4F@@eE8bpnHCCziOsbbUiTrFe1llHBh88CQZTRLYpJi4VnYt64fcqCL62mo6eTJImqw5Q8pRdrN3gxXYkQ6tPBBID6nSSKnOXExqeRUzmW/HVBBamOntJhhg9vsZ3nw4xBXds4gmLY1ZMdCehGpWkQlxIWeMq@1URafyrePmLW1u/baFAGr80zOrNDnTtZoLnwDJZT5FcdagxEJ4@wU9bSpRy4aD4a5O1JvoeyY65ltHq1brnurIbAwW5UmywdtJm11gsfJRmYanymmSVOMLc2Ih7B85eeYzaeJeF1tYrxVm5Nb6LCIZondVDypxP3dlrGPSfESFr1moomHFOMOJ6Ub8ffjJjW8uViCaJiyvGqyxGhCZDQn8miBmiJTTKW7U4i5T@M@RY82UQ71tol2dv8sJOq0kZxxeWqSUk4uQU84bselTZJLww6ML@AmTjTcWEjFCue1N@GjvHL@FE6GkSAAoRUH@WQfSnZwk86a4iOODtBxmrAWKkMS0dOmbeEQO/2PCcZe@fXmjrZ4aE7y5ZMNgXQdQ6JVBee6CZK5b06vx81rhjJDChric0gRt2hGNp3fvVV/ti2UjyBIaU7Wlr4lD41x1SphQ3/spOY1dOCkKl0yNaLSA6HJooHGAq1SzrqBLFeh/YUj4XhYN@hhRAsI@ezgZ1WXgDvv9VJMbRS5bk@QxdXkltHmqvymFEkYSt5Bfj0URdXlhSsBCARjKl8tEwS4NWXscSjArndszkshqvuIClbLGJb0kb2iJnaec9JBVJ3h0WMrR2lejmc2jPxcIKRYzM@TIEI6y/wsCRSa6ObiYuV4Mr89SQ5SiA3vC8WpK3SvpGkY95wQkENnl9xEohyXlVfSHMyJjx67qcSYvzn1WclKLU2nEn1iDI/z5enUp6VUaqratbV00VRJoodr15pKJFK4NsKxVPhz//HVFNvleWwTai0yUlqGts9GaHNaZdK6rfBrpJ7zpWyjYxh49s1ws/xqSoiVlFP2mx2wqxwfGcB3@59urbFMNZjoWAHsl85cdnFkQcgaaxZTPZqFla7xtBc7KDBr2kFHvT/a3U25fT2dGEOjXjB6XCqVwMSntvN7Y1uNraRwUEznLnYuut3i8Oovo/enRZb9QcAhASpmBR1Ql9CgiAqD0ZlEhgAOlBW58/oiK9b6F52OHYIBJ5ToPOo2yam9ISiegMLY6OX9EW8AMUg9wf6CBqJ9v6h49F35omhqKOYYikrDJPgya07PiDz40IF9dnxSxcAgmI01E81bbnXzC2YQRDbhzmL3xe6XxDw5@yrodgee@oAYyfAUsPRtusDurl2gJFlwwsi3ey8i9kfrqeAy7Fr3ipHF5nWAMxOTiTNh/MLDN/5BcFa/HjrZ45@zNK1Qk1fRzFX4p/ZU9izramfxdwArfEho3yl3zx86LabTdGaa6vUITp4Io4dlb@7aJ5XF5T0xTbPbc4Oo89EtsLMGarrLuoDxZc/dyy1ZkD0mbvbTdbkDGpYEhsYJPlfuVgJXzf55YvFy3OncTSpyGADp2O@SiBIJ5c8JRD4D4BGohx/RE160f8rTsN6dcigiCg6CdczKHRRookAmc79V/e3KqdVqamW4uqpqtS16yOdVbaumdvBha0vt0PsW3n@orj1@vCEyd8f9Qh@3zMdvaotg8A7naut8tEOvlFbFvTFYa6OLV4rVFW9jpVl9vrkRFY9rW7jWT0///l//@7//t/9RrOmX/4WXLX45/jnOVCgUiiutLys/fNvA@/HOSW7l9HhleJI72wCX/Z29hg8a47yfmI8WRqeZZZkFrK9sR2rW2ex9RhdVJpZfzx99JulSUcutqLisv0YSOYpl7HIrsL4HuEd5Skt4E3RgeimfQVC3nj/Bdjz1TiuAAR7NN0RJwgV2oFJezlbMxj3cwcQZ4lOVZe2Jh3XWywB3WhJPCriLSzNWPuxHQR874Jes80rzMhmffsNxU/Nv8ec30dnW4Fo9@OSoByX1wFMPsln@Ka8/o6/uSjHE7VzJRsuBbNajlORoAWaGKgpZ0eP1A8famSJ3JrPCIXsAybip4MxyC86LV398WUYCrkVnmSWE@1SyRcKHTCiy/GWl/4265Qvl@JZNXbVhRaGpVzFcmXWiEvcvVCA/EkOApOaeEKQyoCpx0sc3kvFUNF90X2c4mhADBlkPXu7yuMcHmotW@trmObWWQpgjNp@Xr5gbN@QyNKONFKk/QYAPVGQ5WeKbhLnlXEasvK1WcjPlFrbdPs18YuswCcbGNl0K/U1ZTCDW3DbhVvr6Xos25JbjFZUN4@MVq6rstO23ylhFehfdcTjU1xW4dgyoL3Ft32QkoUcZkMARn/2V2RHGGwXGU9RUt0iwrIlqD9B0GQl9fTWdOtgtyMmRRYTizw6N7a9TY9st8i0Rww7CA4xUbMrX8cNupL2ujJjYZ/7oFNEB/Q4HVBvLuRnv5yFq6xTGg06MdIEhs8l5Mp6pKcvDkX/W8z21vDc4GvmTBk1bpPmMWwWXWggXTEACg09XPa95BmFpke4SpkjcFLYcQvCC7kSHR5O@zcZ3TtClZihotysYBCl2YkoGX1N9NUXHhKu/oxNslGeEd3waqUUsS15YGmlIWfvaDA@zmaGTMTXYYyceONmMoBqPTMMLutAFJtoeH/ySJO/CR4CuO6tvAeqrCOvPUD9mp7Og76cmp2E3Yy76FzeUzIsYzxyKUqyRMhrKk3IS8Q5YkR75c9oLhMxNxp1RZslxlj5FOpzbsj2PsJPv2Ba/6KswDkDHAcz4Zoh61w9FWE7NUEkMjIJqsOU/Qeh0/TPCb3LlT8CKn5adH@8V3eOfP/VPHjif@l8//e4yJlokm1k2r5b1YbaRWHqs0MxY9FKvxiotMq4GP/XTGT71ldxhsUhAiBSd45@LJ1@LhNCnZdd9UPy0LARJdRkwKd5cXxHgizNoLqexKC5nltwHrul858eyq2hu5V/0oXxw5ZewMItK3qandc6oQ6D4nu5vF3LlJCo@XSs9Wis/opXQWXCdHwUXmG/z0cVpcE2qRITlLE09n35PcUOKEN@uI3@DPl5TOyWsidw9ifQlJS1C9TDnejIxW1GZgvAE5Scqs7tUXHFx4zw@Dh@x4PcUsZzJy76gxHTQ4j4H82c06KEeP4Jcm74dIhwJKwOxEeEt1Dwgm@ArizjUNcMlx/ecCmobvlsZCHVvcdmaLfqDfl4ra24htwElGrdmuk9LT0vTY3RmiKZG6IpWpnL3VHnzxyf/9j/3f1seL2@uFT@M6He8/Nvy@tNleaQHento3i6XN5efI9v6t@VJkdbA9Pjk3/43ld/8C8FByuQ5/dl8bGCtT5Y381Uu8nV5c50eymtrVO//@dd/pTasyIoNsVhXmp5ixDYMRbb9PvMupasGWinL0lwiVvhiFmCIhSGtzekFhlHXa09LvE23rK0qLgPt@crYo@gpng2zxmwqJDsZxp6CNCMpUEUFeQFpTCg6yrLdMGYbYN4ETfXL/cJ6RCuAX7Q5R1xlbLpxP4LJ0Iosi6gDHamR1vPysFn6MRubd1SyxqZkw6iQWNppWfv04Qaxw9tBMA5baSsJM1x7Lf8qOC2ADwtB@4LWVP2oO/h1VLwkluyV154WO9jcL7Idd3HIkPLDSeF3UgR1MCBaGLLRqadG1AODHlx4eRwtiBT63fhMysSTJC17GLRkDysdk5iyyB0/T46H0ZxCoko7/JcUeETO1IEgrVhpn/pUcv@gorKrcUbJx2teF9i8ZeNY7QIjL9awQ5ZNhQy3AbuDpj2F2uiMLyFxKXhdlywFv91u@jrNySxlTag0L7N0HnSH1WxH3LvDdypOTDT9Rc1cCCUfYgchn2dBB1i9YOzTEr2a5S9Yjyc1wE2KPmuNXcUlZO3ovHpV365y1JUbqr6Sqq@oR6ElJPXEPGN5Y1N2NpEtVWxVjoImjtTmVky1RSZo86jAP8Agkm5pdHAtQTeHb0AS1ZLmaKsyu9s8XgsTj1wFcmdPthYlcnVmObn86JkccoMauhPqLUhlJCDgBbcCC2V6P5QbEFUTZjTsZ8Sf31Sy8e@hwXAb9uFK1HZbJ85HZVrqXyL2TTjmu5SKSKD9yto22BmZPWLQsYutOARtFhsvWRcs1anwYoszmu6ocBho4xIqm5V9quOWisPLdnT0WgkUQR@ypfLaw0eP1588fYYoZ0u6tfPBoFABq4DhuU8wWKN2aJGN79VqNpeVTwhBPVsloM8DiwM4mHVdua5x@3zl3quWSxpYKcuwrjiMhhTX25UMMoE4CgqYEWiN4oyyjvNj5RgNO/nUdr/SP@Jv4x@QGc64o/WF9FY/vE08U2V64nCgyoKZneI4D@FBxdUpdt5g0DmAt4kAtq7C9lTRa3iAGJ@PBhdn5zZ3FLRrqyMaMERw9kuNFdTLYJw4GLOwgi6qNxwa1u2LqoF3PNsCGOViSoDOJ8BpmGm/lb62NMXoyNEkBM@auLGKI0TLdNRmZ@bO/kDV93amEVu2w9Ax3IJt2UrKHXsygwMZxOq1mntE1NXeLvgqqZZJXsqrMgu4EvKV@Tq8j7vSLQSitqhiZDXrDWPnJrKUmRcT16ZJUepH4DUHZrl0OynNvVbTChDECEK9mxQLMS8@z7FJluBkdzLGKXg5W7FsRN@EUcQO5nRlWVdblHImjiqwlFkAEPs2paw0pFRBj/JjnQMvS28jmKPcisbWgDZDjleqwdycHGaCrW4jcYCNqOOGFmh/Y2/bUzt1@rP7YceDorxV@wntjkM8L8a3rPEtV1Rj13SB7S2WbW5hM/UbrigRs5S0w9gEQQjfjkRFDBKvAfXGrqa9DOrj1Ng@SbgC7OprJdzsjupBAkcvvAeypBfvsSsOvq7D3yqyeTUraWKXKnpYyBbXzQPboslSUmsMSUh5BxBr0yBiRy0Jty8lDC8W6Kx5@3rtYhi7sTufp1MsKwsqUtt3i0T2NM8upMxNbLGm2WKtgn68iS@Yb2/kjdOgM9B30WLmuIU37v0x3sjfnTny/18wR/2fwx0PNXc8rED2CHfEbsP5RieHYR/M4ZjTCc/BzXZ4FmJ/qGO9ohElzwLAAg8Y4g4pJZZLaNsCcaKc@Qmr0/MRjITWHuNiwB9q/CPd@EcVyFx@3An@X218/h/c@Me68Y8rmGvm9LxW7Sx36/@YFicqoZP@MLd7oe5KNvePtnRdt3S9gtl0Tjf/p7c0/x/U0ie6pU8q8JggBw7ivv5mbhZNpHa43Wgk5haFjHba5SCO/XyudLH2aleztHjodC@i8yq0dfWH8X@q8X8KacRPCEOHs4jYNjRey8vyVC7Li2bJuxwKl6ykJdJe4xndaq@esJL1iJ6gREjzxtZIL1RIIfckMTltKiT6YyJ948nnrjiLbNfBMnFwbi2gZUVYdpMhLpqvDpK5th7PKzvsA1ltHx28Xv0vQoae/1nfQiPk0bVXQbdrZhJ7CXYUe53SjbGaA9iHes2RYhVNTkZ2rG97x@yytFiqsWOLqXlx/iJBjtpw/kdrqR70DSsqN7aMiDYFXd6sqmCaa5YX8oXaLpnmN1m3@A9x6TPNpc8q6kAvDBaRytcbfpoXk3Xa2uPHN80BUqqAHwzAkkf5bxhV/xc)

[xs tutorial](https://github.com/TieDyedDevil/XS/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md)
[es manual](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/manpage.html)

rc/es/xs code:

```bash
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
```

xs is separated from es using differences in lambda syntax: `@ args {...}` in es vs `{|args|...}` in xs.

I could not place this code on a single line because of rc error `syntax error near 406`, so I used heredoc to move
the code from line 25: `` `"<<rc #"`; `` (space is for Pyth, `r`  `rc` for SILOS).
`` `" `` in rc/es/xs is equivalent to `` `\"` `` in bash.

This created two problems:

First, `null variable name in here document` error in xs triggered by Minkolang's `$$$` and Rail's `$'main'`.
Fixed by placing xs code before Minkolang/Rail. Note: cannot use `<<'rc'`.

Second, `rc` breaks CSS script. Fixed by moving the top of 2L code above `rc`, so `rc` is hidden inside a function named `*`:

```
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
```

Answer (score 0):

## 407. [dotlang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dotlang), 17171 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x               :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@   R[+++]._----.^    p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@" , `'[]'[]` ;L    >"082",,,@_     xx-----xx       ##### #######     #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     ####         ###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53'S  1111    \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx             2222222222 @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii            
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11      xx xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++] +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>]( '4o'6o@ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ <<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM             @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e: 
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._#/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWw//wwwvwWWWwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{   #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\';     `"<<rc #"`;     a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit;  #{IO.puts 295# ['];   print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1')or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68')));[exit];  '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"';  #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180;\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;'
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#= +
+ *   +
#= + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       +
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@*
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
^* *
 #+*****|
.x= #   +
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu#
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178;
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ;
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<  
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120.
>X x.   ;-}
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp; 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230.
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa

+ f
#&
__END__
#n::=~147
RA::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/;say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405

































































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script>
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){
g=window
e=g.external
d.body.style.color='000'
d.body.innerHTML=e===null?334:[ ].pop?
257+[10,,,0,,,18,2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308}
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> ->
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
9#""C""Hata;re7^0::Prullsge>Ex Crithary,8,3"t"F :n^*2giogrlopstdisp[*u""]!!48 在ｕ?2\0C0+---ML42yad=1/;b=~ 16mb|>^ ?4o@  let ,0,1._e#8g=:
 
+ f
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//*
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//"
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//())*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a )=>K a where{k::a->String;k _=show$ (id::a->a )pi};c=l (- x )`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0::Float ),toEnum 0::Num a=>Enum a=>a )+2*l  (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>;
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72'')';end !" );main(){puts('??-'&1?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/*
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAO␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF
 /._++.._#;!;.;_;++.-.>@
#:  /
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[ ]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+-        &:>g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({1e50f606-787a-49a8-8651-d9e733e4485d}+<>2+^              >0  ^
# {\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )#9)print 379#s()
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce:ss~#
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;         ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// :~-<~ -< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PKdSD4USF4fkQWWN184s03i6yurq66XVf9UnX1vdci2WyQBEl0gQAbAKvIrmKHpNnVWrZn1qORHbLs8ZU161l5PRHjnZgZyzv2TIS9Hycc88k/oP3Y2HBsWP9Ae04mAIJVZFVf2d5wLEgA@TyZeTLz5Dn5OOjq3uinP03gRZ451nxoOT7xDc8nfdc8M1yR3J@Te7rpFVSN4zDUnjucjg3b96pcgiiEWLo9nOpDgwxMyzfcHPEMg3QNyzkHf5WQnak99Yx@A2waIbZxTo7sntkHCMR3Tg3bfGu44Jcn5IFhXY4vfdJzxmPd7ntk4pq2T30LhDzTwTKY9k6J3vV8V@/5pmODV5GQF7alj7t9ndDgE9dgkUoEQPVOaZxVnzIhjx3XMyAFp2d4noOOFXDUXdN5tPfkoyvhFZl8pEOmJpYxu5K8opBPTcPtX42hkk9ODg@vumrkK4Jjk8PrWVLyZG/qO0f@VfgFsjc0bJ2oYkVUr3oWAZm@YZXlsnzVqwT1afhmbyUd8Dg0XahdPahF0tNtqC2sywwxxhN/TgRW/7plRXXrEd0jU2@qWzScPR13DTcM6Pm665v2kJyb/oj4I9OL4tHQ3kTvGULfsMyx6Rt9YpkQyRkEUAC03SenxvzccaHKA5iObc0hotEzByZGCfMBAPFK@SODwRnrc6hk24fGQXTiQTYsI4SW5hIQ/oHRnQ6JM/UnU59A3vqmp3ctANqdk74x0KeWnyNd8AMkU/fzkWEHjRnAiQDixGG5ej2lWTOWbV7v94kM7RjycWoQE7BGs1UlmgbuxHEBaxAqzFEAjLZrVkZjBnUGVTRwqqQgy@B/ELlgbnXLc4LMrGYNPW3oq7TOEO4z1xm6@hiw0TcoTj85eka8nuOCDW4My/rTTWB6uk92dkjy4MmDJGlE1SK6XS6qojq5gCpIhJ7kTLem0ELiNeFA/bhRbA6rLLmVrJIkoEWVST5P8tBty0QtAJIUuQIG6P@qpsBdJGqZ5BXoQQWiqaVkDtMauPrQtAwGaYiQStj4IYgKTzlPNKXMQg4da8CC9WiCJaKVSbFESgVSgmeFVFRIEcHniVIpwF2EG6BVIDsK3BpkTlYZsGX7h/aKbW6fDPSxac2DFGgSPVJQSAmgQr4VgK6WAQq8NQ1vDW6atdUrDtsfAdZH@hmAFyzzFKmSEREmrEoJXlImI1HKiKSXJe@NMHlAISCvUCYlSL4I2MhDFgDDahmSL8isIN7IsKwg2sjDaDS3JRluyHkJcFGGWpABnzIitAQ32IHuqUDgVKBmKhAoFYiKqoJZwyQgXBH8ilClxTxLZqR7p5AQS0ft0woAyg5gFMQ4EjMFkQQQoMYIoBqqOw8NQsMGUdAI5B/yUioSoGdlhZTzpFwigM@KTKB@FMgXthYF6KgC@VEQGLQBBRqBAnlSANsKAFW0AuFiyFY09Ie4GsQF1Ch5iJMHM1ScUsQb4kHrUCBJBdJU1cqyMULe1AKUt6DRVqoWoXZL4Ad4UyGvKjQpFXKrlsEf45YBh2VsxNB0GSJ0xAPUCjZ7aIuAjALkh8KFsGBWSxrDn25NRnoXqTaL2R1g1CJ2hyKiEaLKWDx45xGbkBUZwGBPgOyr0AI02mvgnY@StxQA0kTwRt@khNoygYYpEYZKOdogX@sTf4k2pUhzNJn7o8hNZW4OEFATiKAx1HvzyBN6YC7yXLoWNXRVKc1dApLz6OoBhXWmnrUEEhnyKk3KODOtpVuZuvUNvT8wvdG7ZV7zNJGuofu2ebpMpVDIxZCqxzyK6LHiVNLiYX1TgGFrOELTsixqCcNMnKiCVrKsKDR7XWMwtYeGUCnH8kd9/KnrwwCzTLPCnF1zOISxeQlHydFi0gFz6VygObQ0zeciR8QupumaMIzfJb0RMBaRZ4XBr1SWMDQVYcz1Lo7uAnBjMBpUcPwamDPSvdujo8cygxrFU29kTsLA1Y2BY5VLE5mVi7G2QTH3tixH5BmvtvjaMe1UkiTT3IKDMYdxmPERGwa2T3G0wvEXmy6Mrw7lHpbkM2WHI2QakLY62MPoawEZhUrp6TgS47hk0HE1hGP6IoFEgB00nDNkX@nguJKMRwfQrovcKnA7fcN1CYYFFtfL0aHWm3Y9480U@allvgYwdhswxA9004oyQMcR3aeMALyTHqQ3X832wHXGdLAZ41BqOc5kA9sCA/c5AnronBvLrC/HdX0ysYB7AneDMW@QmXOd8t2USY@nyjIEkTAeVDgApEkB12G6Ro/iPig6xNaAP1nNYpWojbsaQrkfY6s06CzAcngYx55aVhX4HaNHtIbUN84kdGGs1yrLhXkImTFgqQIQXR14Zsw5zUUE6a4qUjbvJKxZzxmvFo2Nr0dR0UcmMkjWuT6H2hvA0GrM9DFw9gTZZ@i5ZAwthtUg1gTILlisI9J37KQfQTl3gZmFQkcloQwz4sQ3xwZIQQ5EwRrP00zj6E5z1p1DU6bYyotU7GE5uYIokbuKKOaQjzmwzgJsX3/aQ6xh2qZNWxCwSh7y@i6QSubG@S5ptXS4XeDrJoGkJ6IBAz7HrMUEBY/19oAD71GIyKsatgfihScSE@UwaPlDZwCN7dyEsgPBgqhL2D2KBERB5DQTeyJHUY4NaHxqEZP0JhMC7jAoQfM8lMvAijqvTfIWPK0RiBK9qevOyWwCNWGOIZTfcwYDaL1vjckIQJBxn/TmPeieUMnYeri@QwlMb7JazKVt24AwNgon@89@ngwNQDswrgOUUrHJLwswmdAiUFToNmNqbR0whUXoTeYULVxiGWPgOCK69x3Do43FcU@jro@JecaQdg3oZ4MlMRojkw6t1KbCRR8oT9C9ED4myK0tDCYVtIKPDBu6Tg9aJXR6qD6s0z0yAGE7xsKivKH3esbED9qJQ8mZacf4/qeHyPdTVyEAJnojbvse2bnSaiBo1HJivCzKQZj1SSCO6EhrA4leoIxHJHoyymLNryUPIc6upM6/wjArOXjFb8jDhHYJFIIokZj6SEqQOpq9EdJCH6kN5beht7nT68UHt3jy7pgIgyhtzI0CZIcTpcgJ87EZhgC3dR2QOLEQVmPFAYOuONwCWvfGayA7USatftxVlHQRiOJtQMeO7ayBCsiM4GKQVR9aF7QxPkeqoVtRY6TdxVupIyTYy0kmHMhgDJ1MHBd6BiM6czqjQKss1roCQTwVjRVpkdxfHVphyEjigO/jKAgRJpYObQG7GPZUkKx0oBRAxJigDDTPYSnGMkx7PYUV5O@ckn7WmGAstW0DhTPdnTMgUDwYniGhOTFdF8jgGQ4SbAwKBxORtlMYE/R@HykrooP2@6uJi9ii96ddc3ZVGu@ho/ja4850lwxQEHeB6YBOlEoOvGS6Rt1pzJgXLzkTX6JR2ZOHgDSQCFWeGoBsD4PEIRCa53O7l@JXuhifI/zUH5T5NBgwIuPRyMcgKlzNHYoP2GjGp9Cvqa1GhjB8CwI8BXSjOUEPSUQP3QU@AzohSJmVSr@rk0ugHi4RZvtMFAlFEkXMR2kZdj9KK0AE5iVeXpEl4bk9ahBioxqWAIPTktNBYgWBH4gJGpEHB0kKxlZ0oNwe86N8DXOc2nQ@jqQYK5ImFxHzCwNAimbGBObD7Jl@J2BX7t4NGZeteh0aG3BTQDb76bhEG05cikCpIbBIuZEgEdF3nvvYN1JpKC8GXrDcANsELbXeIBf@yIUeR@0LDgIBWjkbW3KI2KCen5in0/7VirbREQPx2OuAaTJ7Pl/jYPBnvaF@E1aTK1gFqTeJWMXGi/Ep6GuNl7pihfJBMNfwkP2tB1mJ1XAKcxC01bUoYlEDt2WD3p/3rIAlYCbo7IwadSH7p8GEVkSIcgFPEHbaaz2VAcHuwOCQZ3snD@tBX2SeUte0qysOltPTLeq8jcH5MO6jo/vHe8c/31kDwzK71asOkpkvF3Gonc6EoT2V8qJa3Y7DWAJ@0LkZNkZcDcNzgTcRnFmMVZr3YHCZheh8evyVqygBTgjRQVMAM95XWBoWBpgurqt7oyuDMBlms5BkFCUMS4QjEsKMDJh19NfD/Dybvn2LlXc1U5PAHXNmTXUGIHSUjuwwnoieVxiw0Ks7YCMijQtcqGnjgsPSFA8Z5ucj5JqvZoay0rEm89HTw4PjOgUbzKsJNIjk@cBL6W5fhDZvTUEEXxcGyB@YeiQrLjOO/DTN61oE93orCF7WLdkAHwCgrCM6RLDGYdG8EeR9/2rZqKvQi1oAtVMIV/nKOD/U@6IZjeUDh7geirzrRlHqsRysIqe1I1bkuzps9QoFo5SvxIet3jLNfhwoXRyAcSDkG13wOvUEdBGXXGTAVgfZf/7oWsY9ykSCKCCEOfMsItK0PItD6UUwSdKT9kFCcyxD/JRSPJ7waUlKhusDYs@jwmcs/MHM9FNymr2VNISF1Pf2jtQHYeBgyprOZFChAWVxHJncAa7z9TxoI7ZjOUOHZCAO4w7DBIFt2ljMvaFjX6shHR2xqAlcKgT6ixM3@gTGGvMtFRxprLi4yhYddds7ByqtFDVEEsUQBSXR8OJr/UwHdC3L/fzoawcwiCgFWY7MMr0ABbE4FF1o6sVcqQMRICExyM/aAkbLhtd6e@ghxNbtsNABoYsi7i291zpSiilKa8OvzdLHzjWMv3bmV5oWuLCmBYYYyo6ePHt09OTg8d5nLV8tFFbseblSBMRBel3ghcQRwxv21gzrmlgsBJeAvuFi9wIqMAUBJVw1mnouEG4Rg4gsAxtaDVtwTX3sjOykl75amHP0FV7bPdaEHmPnY0GDiCBo9y0URly2ao3jObafke9PvKokQS8fTbsiCK3S655j6UOJxoOBwbIkBUWXo6c4r@GtiwGZ8eYGi8Emt4B1mNMZRN0aOyC80LVvJA0kxcDTWSvLHI5AFsYFcsNNi1ELpqWR@iAhgKwsRWWjBJjaALfBO6wnnjXtLytqmbVrRVbzEh8GW@n@EHZrYIDolILRClCRvmIlrbutu2QOVBohXQWSIGKGTnJ4BMcCiwAjSWdNUc4PkUOpBc6XIq2gOHozxdlcoFJSQc6XlGJBArEMxDTgWQWccxPGut8bCb4jADzBGdB5g1grHHg93R6ImcAQZhb4vjtQVK35stWy28Cgt@7SvOH6c3PebirtdI1cj5IJwqdr0HpXiodtN3SAtkuN0DTpm2ygZ339Ojnr67R39YnkjyfBmCNMyOM9YKTeOkCv@0a872EEKe4pZVbCShj4nbRmQsjCqBw@EFMSdCgYaaHpSZgvAZheZA@h5QDdikUgy9mMiGGa@yOgHxpJ7VNT@jqHi85aQDVWs4KTwuJkDiSPBkKiLWiYodCDJjhhEDArSRCBkONB/yTLAttqEiNlKPdj1zOdpEeXaZC1wglbbwL1SOe7ezhQeDhF6cMAHXU@HCigfeE4Qc6NJE7l6x6bMIVIwXaDMD6IixEEujAQTYrb0QYLaIc0Fp0hAOIFTRtnbkfLiU6cd4DGDgnSPOH8BzAxNl3AGEIhITIryB4rCEuJuqwW6dR2zm2E1jVIWeiaPltvcKYuLrub/XjZILimsjAAjRYuNrTQ9fmu0WMTvSwyLQXIoToZG2MHZzOAwaPUyKBF0NnaPoqjHk6aQ8@WBVy0BPgCubcPhLRnsCkrYYxyHLTqA5L0XWlP@JqkC2@hQ93A3mHhY1UcVPpJiIDVnRZ0oiaYhKUMkjOmgT6lUz7oeT/kuIOmhS2L1@vOxLCvip1MKE2la3RHRDLJ1qEukltbW8lqspHMgWkXTDto2kVTFky71CRQE4YT0URj5KgJfZs0Brq1k4tmCHmWbmMbmCHz8tacpPRmtaq1c3pTCd4qvtNQFYB5CC3gC@Ak0/U6GtNpvnGOy0YgQsTKvo9t53nPNScBCj4GnoTZ492LD7qXa9RQPL4ZI@O6C3KrgVxuyk22mnKr3bpo9bOtRTKHsdM1vQ4iKtBPPzUWh64znQDv2MxXBSCv6aZWbde69aSczKRSZcGChPR0@k45ndUZrlNJA9pUqtVKAkoD7DR7I5fCm@XUdDpCFORjYIKgY1mppHhRhvS76XY6m4S46WQORoZ6Mgl4oWueHi00TkqwRnRozgCV0DFhlI0va1AaTdfHsLt@zZiM5m48QDTxB4w@TuIvt83g7iIcSOKE@i2LH@cpVyYbQtabhQP@GucPkWWbzNkAw7GctqSVTVrh0H8mDMaOr0ufiCC3ibERO7mVlAQBBmPqwyDRYj82PezCum04Uy8@2bl2DhZTB9eT0RSIZbhTLgetypxwRm/kkOT2PYBOoiUnJPy4eiawNbgQQL8nwo1EFBkjXK8BBofubTKBLtJdYXRiSKGZYKQnXB4oFCdvxCi1Go1DZEzIHNqOawiAEojB0Y1cdHsg1wiXxo/o5Nu14SfwpaMqDmWmARTx0HJ0iltGrmNLUpNxLL49xCjHRp@zgH4MgDyKrC5coy9lOLpQ7LgjGCGgNEiJ1ai2xoGH5HiTvujPICqXwjE/7skETOB7z0lfVdVirzCohn7YKgDZI6gkFIxtkLJDL0EBz3RQyQdsZiqcJnjy9MEBm76h4z2O8DiV1xk7/SmwtoHodmzYwxw5gPZk2s7YBDSE8d@eWseO47OJBrBsmhxicrs5nlo6nXa6OjN0Y7ye03UsOht1U9Rl@Knr6ZbO5sFC371PHoO48eLkeV2sxgJJ@tn4xrRxKnR9sgyfR/FlT7rkG65Qeaxh8tsFHsetcAMqkpnAo4ge02D7KdRR6F5C97BL4TJO4F5G9zFuPQV2PZjIoNbIMQhYoQFxOyruvQscLxR5ge4bxcAonELDMd51mdsLRaXuZ/5gsOKsUedTAUmTtXTOU2e2LXVFTI1nqcAC4R7VlTBxQEUaJtqqujFciYZjG2zEaHHzcbQPYmRY4ermMXAsuIIHg76FfBXITSglsO2kBjD5E1yooaQbl/9ID/hg7xoXC51tIrDQXGKLdiAY3CRkabhtiQTT7zXahWwnWDb1GFl13Byb2dlpsIV2FOtcJlFKbGFguwMgdhq1cM/fpmCYUjIZBaNQad4gBi0m3VtwrajRThGPzvdzNEqN8ySQaGaqLLRmpYP2ZVLyKBoGhG@1Zndk9TMQjXDj5vZdaWjU6DarDfiqhT7JgIftzokAHB@GYnPnvRHQGZKdraIS6mdqDxyrL7CFOmgwhIl4WEHBPoloQ2mwb9gw3XAvKd3My6IifY1tQ70G90qVNq4HiG1cjQBB97kgl6e5s0vShCHvTPQmlum3yUL0nc4o2KxlX93iynhQ19XnHhdss6mTveOPPmnKbQaBG@u4@FZmtTgLd0oD4wyMEm5pBxNuFvJNn3ICdDOEieVVRMjUjK7TQPYBBkugRqKEghJh1i@Ny2VZBgYIyykDc@7NxzlipBfiwNJ937BZm2MroJvRzZaqgmTqNPndYN2jSmS6OAScqYl@kMUaeX7y4OD4WISW66WSB7iIVIXuqPdGwKBsKnSIyXjhq@ROP0nuYJw0zhxw0NVA@ugE8aFR16DRg/wBqSPtGBpuChzTuP7TA2e65EYjMg4tQBBu@er5FEcRsJSRhjJRYNW1@X9hM1EryGcVWnyWYhLQnbpbBdyaaXFqm29EDwYayrdCkEBYhfGivp2iVGxbSQd7@sa4eg0SFmUaoQTNJhHeApWDwDxpt2tsGwKERQHMHSJ2eZ5WBd1QX1fCqq@DM7A0FEIQvf6OvGzKQqWd3V4Hiu5vC/bCs/LH4CKEVdCesTbZ7RTt79c6MssDW45klPsFFaevHASpkm1m4Nm0Nw0e7tmiRIdu8VrdqrW6EQw6GZISOhuEBQlJQiI4qRC0WepPKT/IPBiNOqTS5CJCuoooJ5eXFIdkWyUUh2BSCKuMRSh9AmF65EBpHgWnFOLcAe2twV4W7LMtjg/FrNXFYvRhLLx0doU7Fc74eDzGHZr2qUOXnCJTRxaVAnKEUezxqXU9Ju6DpY@VoFEeWFh1U@68cXdAH2sC0JWXYE2fOtA5/YAXBiZSl47pi07vr0l5dR/LSrLBDlk60oKZCG9uCSlUyjTwoNs1NwUFJODWtPC9JhgQKWzPqpgXlfDYA07FwHgEhItJL8uiX90CRVbwHmzlDd7/7et9wP/12hnBQIGTn5GhA0M31pQw2FhZQVS00Mf6imVz9FPL1CliqOk2kD3dhSLpVmRYD5ruAxAEGP7HuKoR1Di0TXwA13hDM2M5Z4uS4Xt9IuvW9Wwgmb1NYa9sCWNJ0RUoEOz6FAmMCTINGomSLlYJxoytAsVEbCRjt2cq3LdFaGNm9T6a@lP2BMb11ko0J3jf1DeDkHJB7yqGxDbP31Dlrn467TvC5HQY8anFNWGXpafL0AKwA8GKdAeN64vPCsg2o4fvTcGWQ5t0Tl@3tQrPnnoToUul8D6z0Y4wviEF12LPTUHM4BxhZNiMNdOijw9siQF0aCjBhgwJt7sKMaSZV9Bs6d058iCjL97Kos0NQHHqvWxW1jasbk8mm@OjJEnjVyrrY8/EHsPHujkCiW2pFdgsGi1wsMn2llqF4coc65ag9mPGjcR83d6Ia0GjZVUaB89/0EMgNzZyHJB6U0t3l6YbmvgyH@EywqYZ6WDYeGb2HGAHJkQpiYoaDh2xAYOSzHB33jIh3NFMH7EdGOY6NIYnWoTItJ4EOD0fd61uaFMfQNDYblHckxtrJKKzCVM95xzvjezDCERT9lw/or1dm6sPIE6C1bN0GMc3Dgcrk4M4@XhLQz03PYM@1iP2dG1G/Z611n21C4TTfvFpvNuatWdajkee0@dNCBq6gAX2XN@g47g0dVugk@Fx8w00KNxmsaxQ3Ro6VrE8lHR4bKz1qTtAuh@8P5TCRRRKUW6hUCH749hK8N5I108l9/S2CqJnJl3cYhsz3jDEriNTwdrL5tKBYIALd@tLdiiXaUxRYlN9GxLGJZdzfR6@f4ahYxNqw6FjMqfsNHB3GKFSBoPvMhb7Z0ktf3Nq/Q8jStfAlm4rRKxyTy0DBiv6vFalRJWVLxhDkeUPJ1EDa2pMjbWCxtPuawNP@N8gZHx4puSgGNvBTD0uDuDpmCjU20Ay/KBc4ziNthuJiW6ZPeN2VmaVqE2A@56g6PwMDM/QcD3G0J5OVmp1RTqzj29G2WgSdmmnv5I79PmidKh8C6e0wp97Br1vlJiYhId71OoFWZYDBia24rJiuUmS0qK4r032XEmYuixTXobFVTY3ZlyfBkVLfBfkRhKkbhLsaeBKRbJN2/Dn@PxAatp1HOuL1BQQVTyz7IC0KtDdvjfV2DV2JzjHQpZTFx5OeHQHmyYt2GgTyJaAHxSab6r0@JLQB9WmgIueY1yQWrXePH0TW2C6LRU8X4tzQmz/r7WZlwxmQxSxLJZu7HWMQ3W6hqWz16yYvwleRdRuhLdKNILFWlzcZUu6y6X4xBWiNJkDssw@SCkjY2xQ6w1cvt5HbR3Ba2OgmYP3Ju@ZYfSk2YHR2xRgYgJdsPG5soYcY5Z8xwb5ysethiinWLiZNXDdRIHDVb@1SD4a60ODqY@5iVIuJyxwNw0T65bG9VMXVbaDpgfRlnpBNjcJ6FSnxtwL32sBPp73oF6n49un2650/h7OgX5Ab9@0i/b6EGuPnJE9MkZs63pk29Q5oD36TN3PTVmHXA9HuJtuMlnZZR/Hp@VY1ofgE0kjI5SOM1ibpwM8f4uHx74QXHbYP3jdOnmn@4x2oGFjrxkZUxiXPMd3JoZAbZuCWjjRw56baGi4SP2zziDdKOcDRsL3zwr/VtlyqDv@ZEJfnYk19eiDRhXosenb@KYB25pC92U67lB864y7YuAoBvtW6BL4ehLTNf3eCM@ts5ZtDJ1ub2TelulAV4YUTvkw6wfJrogZkwgP0Fm0TECvOxexvdTj/s/xdbSp0oPZIzasRYYb@JV1M3T0ZLgw0U97HpsNRROp4oRwrDey8@NVegK/@mZq@kugsb1M0fQuW5ZAw6a8B7snNnJW9JjGkgwHuyo2tlLKpCNDLhgyMDzKpmRX97nFupimscemDMVLSXMU25fyRdAd7P2hs4NmbN4W3Ffa18qmpbWDnD2aDr3rBJNN1/eBRcPH5mkLup06NmUNY5ZuB69NaFYtCc9ZwrsDPNfUuHFNpXDjogoNp1iC7pjw6sALqm66cQ7NMiceexJhsHEpLtjLBLL41fVChpv5emE6qJi@MWBLIGi6jUUcOy7uRAYeROjhSjrOoCMxZ4wXI1y2MwSiLlhkGTgMu4ltWbtNaH31R2Om8NkTY6jjXutHpo@bNde0Ctpk120vuhX2V6e6Z351CiXb1NhQaQRbhnTj2gXQtgbeY31o9h6uVESUyQDBwU5P9lpp/uh0vS7OR6aHO5oiww0TU9jkWCPGVtcBuWFNyKvz9pG@jGUHYicx14ZeN7fuTOZ4YG1OTTdNq5s@nWUN3ptEx02bwG7MxPl0PJl6wWt9Huieqfgs9PiUunvnJgAX3gBpJSPd8tfPVMemXIELCwbFpXETN/4103KG5GtlmQDTBkwYMudrGs59GJ6f4YYc117TEmnaH7jsiRMdgssK9gbq1sBzFbbp3zyb4/u4OSd8Y2HYyIEnFKRH@BTvfVEIwsl6jDy6nddfno6@ZXyHlvfcmbo9A42RypO4WBCkauyHu4/xRIeDKlvO41Jaz7Gge4HBWttleo499QV3at84KhRvHBWqqPAq1gxI6qsHj1@k462B7ta@jQsNVaItTRs3DFxpZKYNjNhmOroaOpQlHjBVTcd0q/AtcfZQn1SPkusHzjp559kcBpAPFpiA@E/HD4weLhvemvYT57FjOzAaTYBQjo8NpnZgZaPH@ogY7REerAf89G9N5jkFu2EQYtyGPjG6UL/W0vQhYxED/ED39Q1DEZ0bpPJfZLq1rZhW13Bf00m/mHmTSLuaoYfGjMoWmxsM64OC3@sxlhjn41b6yMqKjTdxHJs9KbWV4aU8vpmqwFBAHx@@UC7iRvyVeYG18tlqUZ@esV0iRp/pxdhUVtfoOhZ73rAnyTbZngDdNQ1PeoRqFqhbMU8E4L68G2lI6UYashSNgJM90z26SL9e1FiCVGZfYAvQSHd7Dq6EBYYbdufEdCPcQqajvf1s40AXED8DiqX3poG@0tuyZY27Y/rYKDDEavPY6OKpoC5VKOLrs@uVyWaGAm0KsR1dkQ6CkFxhpy6S1DOQRtK3D1srctQqVs0JfVBKvXG5nG7WEWzT6L3VcdbMofhazk2v@EOZpSfUuGGuOtaN6CyypNPD9mt70urWNWBoLEPwRy7I/JJ/0/R2qOllzXrIdGzgIvPqKsxG1tXxRrSwzvr19Ii4uoYQqBsEWhKpHmT8obC3kfNE8PB/ev9jCQbhTjEfaj8B0nX7Cj5kfurawetDWuAzx/MH5uwp5BtPAWwiJ1isAkSBF@sZaMpsKgTUnj212OzDMLbvatyn4phAFUILgkXJtW8Ihn0mUF10s@slctihL2kPFQj7Rl8IVDHgSoPwKDz/FQUL3msWUOO0ETd7KhJD7KyYD7Z/rkPueUgZgN9yfGHi0bc08Z4dPXp6Ik48Ze34tDfC0xHX@LgV3Q5qWY5NSb3W3dh6J9uO1jc9X7r/XBH2Hx2JGGADvtmKhgAvXJlbeW2c9wwVyUr6RikIfQ1/PYP48OTxo@zyiCZJ7Y9cZ2yk4977z5/n8KTJx8/XesdjH0LvGDizjdGPDhQlvab5vrDp6uAm6rkmpU2QTgyQRqExPmSqYW5lrnrOxOifzCfGJzB4IgX3PjD54sZCPtHPzCH2QlLZiCjaUUlFLObTsZ3ZIGwbbvTeVJ@n5gSpZY@@JPbauB0FOQdNcrX13MNNK/5XuRgiBzsRvlgkRb7eWuOqjCXd@7tmTFGUTXh@rg@gXklhY2WtBli3Pmw5Zx@wlGwEwosQOQk@tCrBvHUfeUkYA@mW8IHT84EjGLsbt8HcBCByLq7t8OeGPddtga5l3cReVCE2bmq7McjXjA9YkIp2@JyhvvS1a3zRlnqS6lFj@paET9xYlP39@0e3RTgOcHlzqI@evCDPdA/1oNwcMJ5j4wNyvOSMXgs4b4VK@DYup/ZdAKXeCG84Wd@fq@S57vYdez67fRGOnkHFoZ3qN45goY0GMixzZq4bq3psXuvZ@m1Gt6XNDnE48xU@OK4fJwD0/lv/QlFkmWo/wrciM@stNRN2cJJCkz5HlXpxr5OjiDT0kG8RwSG9Vhp9ZMxwOwqbDV4n1K8d34o3jH2l9Obh5Ca/8g1@@RvSu@aHjkQTZeUGgIUb/EhBjLwfOdb5yBH3ddfw1uw/XpuhmwpSuaEglRh1DhS204XFwLyZxcejC8FrbWs9MXw3Pxk5XTO/tgx7A9RzSR6jvvbr/sF2Ct2l21uGTnDkg9nXp3c@NdYm9Fh/u96DUprTtV5ABI3RlB6JuO69ukDaBZ7XsIcmU/FI7jv@AbXdIJhFJ57X70UwJw@mk805BtqIX8W4Ss5XAn4KMrNz7pH7eDRuyaavkf1xf9x69008LYkmBlHT6cOTvbB1PX0uqbEUl7n47NmKMx4e9Z8@j7m5xmy2SegVZptkyLU@y1SfnORXkt1pvDxbg6zN542A3QB6HL038kGM2H38/DpJQPFt5I@t0Odj3V7OmK5UWN/x6UnDtZ7P5jO6jXJtTY/YLrZ1fm5vjfOKYA8DsmlC2p7U6aA6pk5nU6s8MT6jaw/ABhGfsSUMaKB4yZjlR2EOaZSNHdU5XTI/K9l9PhmZ9myt13hTHLqLNPXaW98N9shzyzknjyKtQpvIg7oeuH5m2JuI07rDikJFu5kL066wVJvqhX1AJXhtqpL7mxi1KzQDN0TcRE0w/nFPOgwtn6jpW8N//DwMfnvYfcvB@fu@OR3fHpiCzWZvD@jeQP6uAjRvD4bfGzkdOa59e9CwOVWr940PzMTWB4ccz3vOB@ShOxjcHujAc24P9Hhq@SbKLOuDPnGmFmoQWOd34A7Xujd2Gq2WWBU3eaJCd2/kpjf7475IZ@qBDGRGxDOKKLw2/RXHsM3E3VC/vGGLtpO@Avdjh3wFNcmvQcXbD6yjjw83hVtdsJniEj89Ebw0btrUO5lrt3byt@aQWj6k09nm@MawS5V/R65jM1t60/C4VP@3JqWHumXeStDCDQ/qLVsfcEBj/uRMu51qAYNwuLnOPpnPluLmauktpnRind@@CkgZ9nrp8CNIuDVd0WKTfmz/meFtnvajo/9XD8Z6zwsbGjqx7QXhArK3iROIzyAs/ZjGAhjw4h/c8HKBvjKm4YPpVfDE8KsoqZQN/SK9@gm6uJIIVEuf2ka1zNtUIQSEvbwkW4ESBvDgQ7UOgdoJ1N5q2lMD9UawD1P59W1Ipl5XChWyi998qxJFpmni5ywrTElmmFiTbF8EKhWqVWVBtuqEr/IkUGoR6bxnetsBMGqchkIR4VQh2z74bIcKGQj9BBG5JHQeWeihYl@wiVJcNU0tUFkBedq@eHb07OD5yd7Ji@dNub0IVFqEpbBtSC1UnHNH6/NQ@ABvIJ@yrzhQVSoWJEc/j4Tzz15YLoKfXFstWn2laMtC8bsYZ/vCtiWJavWQhAXkT@BZatQXuSxwYrDDEtMKChS6VJmCDaonBOqIgeZpmlBpVSKvS3iig6y1bQf@V79QSH3xS5ZV/JYlJhwo3oeWOHScfpCiZ5DbrzDFw72jRy@OD0iYwWWrOTf7/qheKbDvMjBNQ1BPA5Nuc66TZBAlCXVVrycPk4CYpJgkVaqHhX4TARo6BAuxgxpcgtgZktqm8AGDyahSpP/2dWmRFPHEThrCJsNMJSFZaPO0oWxtbZETaCTkwfHRJwfHBPN/8IA6I4oQBDlBJRB/@qM@@6pQqKQt/IqnO6aCEVVyxcUVwYTaUZYKXBDntO9ONn/Lk37Fh6pJiT4fFH3/jOPo16Wg3Z5TFa9XdG@mqTo89u3RQDVqmBBtQuGXSHBxGNWcIsk1PROVtGAeBqh1dLWx435SquxXJHv4oVL8HKpOP3EFWZ/aPtPsF@j3SkBLEyOakyPbNLPsg1h8LGByZwsae9cAmZl4tgmjtl8lr6El4gJslSnxEYRG8lqUEHSVmgSUs2IBr6kp9aSWK73/lX8mDWsEzD6Yvx2YZ/J9sP1SYBuA@ZeZ@aWEDe26WtNlXuIZQm3IQQlYRiL8I@5j32e1meKkJeJQ@2pIWIk5hmo6o1jH4CwF9hSAHi/hpJqfQKVBc4MaCxQmsfQMt51CdcxVScImhfM4ImU@jBnbO35FLXOxUMwrEmRSOAsB0u@oDFEpBgOYTlehm3Bn5qT@qgtNbWeH8DiZa9SLNVaz0rb9UuNfRRndhrAcDPaQuSaBOBBlGQP8GkE0GH2yShqjIvVKKkkkXH0HhiXqj8MX2u0AETxJAbIYjgz8MMcMP@Xrg4gTqBfv4sdvY9/Y2g4ACQqMSdSU5rlA1dATx4fmA510@RU9pmoIz06wIRCV5nrsA9dUqze2R/F6z1pqyAg/5hX0NRFpAAOlyVdH03jd8p8iiOcIosqva77Nl6Tlt@y2xNomgWb6gzWN2QbzL0rDDW2WlXvvukLl1FV1yIgscu@57eCs9SEUhqRUSdUkpZheFimfX1ukoERBMlAc1Np2CckBmQKS0TPM187E29s/OPr46bPn15QG05DJq8GA7jd2si1BzDXbkSEZL9Zqldw/lJ4/vn8YVsQy08UYNQbCH5REuakky8UoBLk83Hi1aOtyeLV0m3P8KVN/cjW/mnpT1mika/lQ5C@QLj1gJBzSY8JXE1fL67BVKNyUpSU8KQZ6n@l4uJbVVPpi0WyDyGgnktdbwpqO8DIhZrATgKnlZbYlbOzXC4cFiz49f4If8/TifVFb3xf5bQ11UqKKGd85XWrtDBxiHrHyhskAieREKQy6sfc9ZUz6UresCvQf80dHhriqvliGi/JNGI@BokUFHsdFKrLUjB0ohR6BOGeZXS5UkciUQ4c6bCO90Ey9YSrNBZ94Ygmn2LkdMqvORLqbOJVGakdh5chNeqZDeGkOOjRyd8@mIFY@cybskx9019gDIzQdO0B@H0zZLLNBPp6OIdyAvo4NuoIPlFuAyIDJZJRVxksBlQjUTM@yqMgb0muisumg4OK4X0jN0uLImPXNIdD2VDoHFO2OorRJpIoaC01VT9tJntbZshZu7IofoeaOONq/kD7y2TIDelMXTbtvzFLJ82S62ob00T15/ulZMs2va0tUL3qgKLx/VUF6lP2ScjMl0f2gd4bax9dRi0rlOpUAt6uAmaLO8HuDlYo48jj6/dg6cu7PffcRGIGNSA3G@oSkpjZTcioSak21UnaOan8UGkyBsk2yWSpQwYt6iITGHFATG79Tuj0nKamOnxgGV8/u4@utOSFNRRTbYKaJpMk2fgd0HzguVPub5kAIhihVCraOTQjEDMgR6yQia@AQB/0hLLyoqtg13vSziHSh00Gc0FKTxl0S@67rKufIVyrVoEJXqWKFQOu7Tg5FCcBeo3MhXw/YDfSfAc5A/BW5xJKQX6d4CZpugmXkYaA4DbKTiCk9D/WpEYC1VEneG7l4pw5s6CvAH1SrL04OO@W0xJNIAdvQNfu4EM8@HRKJeMHH3qCbSitBkzUm0X2E0VDVbYdpeEONq4e0w/BXSGoijoZAXXgoLHvLtqkoN7b6IGJQCxAyjwNAcFC9E4JD9cThhNYav/XE/qc/TSCzkdpWlNOOe5ZNFuQaPJRagRTIne2WIGw35fq9bR2kKP/NrAUyuZTJnxkPRoP@0VBq8TzRSF6SMhcXF8nDzDPzZYEUhb6pFt/M5gutqL2ZLTSl/OZ0ohSb4ptZmy/Xc6ftVrNNnj377F3nXZqfnc3f8KSVAllz/ymv5PlEtUIudota4rSCH0AH8eaUvIXrdEDwT81v@zGzjubuAETYJE8SrRZgXOFLvCQ1k234U3H/FVxM8G82xIa42373Lt3UdX82J6ZpTrx@H25nBBykmn5OQF6@C5SeRZBIi76pBAVXYTwDYrdnDIfTA31uTg/9e2JJLItqbHZh5/HXPg2u2qcvXhDygrx48fZ4w1xEO5tNCUKTmmdX/KodvZDAT5j/6Y@3FrmLZ52dP/3GWDK28PUUX99ePEbzc6VwZ2vrzv37@XxOVVVmfva1Zz@/t7eXf5ArPGsWdvOCvLXzJ3@8taWqO6q01fY8pZ1snp5@xqtynhf/9IfJzrNnX/W8hvZ/fv1dQ8FHCR5npAR0Ai6NKGDEZxluBXmsD70SbxPQypXEnP46idD9Yosojd3Sf//u0zcJP9FQpU9dePuJN4liOcGMYACbFtrOEo3EDgYrLhJzqV6vg7H03/8dxG98DHDQZ74Dj0YhhFWcJxpCnUa5TDSKYFBUFdL9v7/@9VgOGZmoUzYuvO6RJlx8vqTyu224MvTa4VCxrSBLUhjO9ke@4RClfFe5ixYTLPCyDfxCiOG3Eko5T57eg5DHzWw22xY7AlziSzpJJCmK2lKUu0AOhDuZel3IEKa6V9MKd/HzA2k6pTV0YMQ07n66ciU@/Xu51oKp/T0APuYSxa17rx40GlA6raFlGll6BV2K9q5SmXecezzJkVdJEEaa7Vek9gi9GrxcVvlcLnevw7rGDLEmzMIuksCLPROJyAU7L7ni1sB@3yaRO4tFrsclcdBrwyUO8Pqz//Bn3/uz79Lf9@j9n1EHsN03B1IGAp1B52jAda9a7TUafMPlL1pob0CLkqvlalnqLFqpTLPRPiaK/NFlsqAlnxMcBxRMo5VuNWn8Bk22ESSP9kZi6dxgLo24W@DBAlMHeAeYIolVrFFzhDVCroSDQTY4LSE0zxptAVmjutBUioW2wGI170Hl8GqpwnfaCWF7DnRHbTfUgvqU3Guwi4y2PeJgbjS1GBYkyG9jWbalz9LWiDslGmG0xjLMFw0X5KnCJZpNqW3QkaERZvTeVnWrXC1WVanT2HzVljHwokENw3jmJc4S0VUjQTsM8ZmIWmbM7WW8JqJqIWEDJitxbwkHdQUkAnoG@8cvNboIrS6tqPC1wKR2eFKD9qFqgjrs8LLCR52NTvTDtQU/@ocrsuJzi7oEzjTI9WuLVJWMqkmFO8UDFQfaW654vjkYMEiv2@2@7XWB/dD1rt7TFV@f6jN9rvvdaXfW9XvTHmF9hixL72pOwSk7oVUUElpB2U7cxSJpakUt4@cjtXJZq6haSdFKRa0kq@WCVq5opbxWKgFAraRqlUpeVbViSSuWtWJRK1bAXYUwRQijIYRSQatoXOJdc4scM7LWJtnwamVvvV6IYicwUoODtyA4swSX@Ae4GoqqkAwMfTI8gN@jRhDH8acoHEkAD3fRfpdpvstAj29kdyi1bTeEIJfwEjv32llhsWiCuVYL/juNyFijFzNB4dqLbHbnZQNYm5eNZhZAvgxAigKhQMVOg7R3qFeUWpBc4L/TBu5IyO40d@rOPr1F2ueENoDcWcnmvXtZEUz3IGZjG/p2OpvdFoQtHHCbwbADgduNbFgegNROkWTeSRadewQK/zPeIEQC/VjsLBqL5s5isbMD/x36XARvcF3sXPvT1/LaEGbp30ba02pKjZbUCuhPG@yi1EAXUWqBoQFvCNfU1HIbRzzkX8T2P86/mFs@IxfMcluEXHOJDMkkUMetlshwiVfvP//f8G69//z3kBcl8DOqXOICKYWUQUm2wgRaeBD7sU0es8sGM96hFV3QofEYHW32sHGxS5JeiaTK1hNSSrmYFnFI7ziDDqrNEckrCLpCWpGKEl4tF/lOVpmrJLHDF0uUhP7ctSuZTP6TV2qllGSTQKj35ZXneY9juVzmEwLXVFkRlMsG@7QJ@wrVz627/snPbbq4xGWFGFXAT4owxHAJaEcJSRKEBpdo7IzxYBAuwwgo8Z7VPxNe7Ak4RaP7dJGtx6Yf6kcH9UqlgfKPsf2M9p3Mgww8FfgfbEEpSGsAQVuDem8MvHVroBXUFn4GIyF03@Dv0Vv8kZMe/o7f4I@cvMXfsY8/8riLv5M3@Nvr4u9kjL/7b/D3@C3@Xgzx1/qSpik1fvuCIiarVJTF9oynCKrBiNVofcl351X6TTde3VVBYA0msVJavpJOtL5kzHrGxK8Gs414Ssvo@TW9Xql162oQNNhijj6i6eF@fVyGCiYXqypJ4zSoVik4roD7IeEBDlmtojhu8iff@cY3kvV6UkjSz3HlwU3oYqAuDQRWiJlnOcHPHEP@oLo9L1m7l/xSk04wFCrtJnq2wYNL1Mm2sq3IltyTla7SBYNJZJfII3mk9BUqiMkGkefynMhjR@mDyYCfDCZTHhB5SGRbtiEY@ILJ78g@mgbwGsJvAIBc@Jm41b6ryD0CCVnIitIvDysdjClfdlpckyQJ/8oASVpURFksmm38WFqTf/WqJWXaaqVMRGzWYqf5qpVs8y0eP6ChVvKkOze2Wq94YDhknjV/dCEJzwPxvJaQWi2JIR7QRWtyseh0Dp486HQkHAlbxGhk72WBwN@7VweCH7x2E43abqtKx4twzEhIO7uthiaguZiF0UBFt@wXvJYQ4d3YoiVvvzp/BQJN6hzFmvMzeJ2Hhk9b8OgwgYd6S@eftmJWapCk83MWeg2EFcOSkYn/QR78h/qb/7j@j1@QNEk12@nUxWInRa80/tLpi8XFIng20qlUYEntwA8dwI5RLhYNNNJAF2BqptLt9GLB3OCZSu8wgA1IZqdB4y7DXSDnG6VJ02WP1N/vG9IOrlbwna1X/M6O2yMJ/hWz68vtPq3WTJbTQKCCj/rg4rV@SfdUpGv0i67b3abS/pMf0g837aZpoEK@VlMyhFnUvFqr5UNbqVyrlUPLdipVuX415F2lCNJQPp9O12pg2Q3BymCFuE3yLkvqpAXP9t27LJGyenkZwtTyxayM26xqtTClAiRreHqPUWvA88XRU/rVI6AShQRBYoATIpQSpGT63TSk40m@yt@9m@obeByjv7uXvntXrciXl5HLZAJOyopTp9M33U4H3bXLS77D0006lQLY5fLlpSJXskoy7bipJ/hRV0gqJSjkjtqgqVaARqv5EngHGSjs7BTzjUYxDy7FchJqr8YINOQ3ySdrfOKCFkMplxj94mvoDCWEDg3jo3exSNC6JPlCOgXELw2c4yKBPxfpJBufCoV0LS/LiYsFzwIrlQoLnSb5YqqcrQS/@laaNIA7Yj9k8bRsPlPK3ANmGX/ebN2FpLR2YdSVRf3CqOJU/6IGI7znAG@DWoOMu3e1CqCmLNdaXEB/6zACIYMFjxaXTGbJnbscqlJyk9XaPVqnSrlAEskacxSSQMdJGXArqZmCUkZkcOYAdYABk8AxQW2LbHEqfeODqzBeagsdQfC5Rvm4PlykT7pkiBcZohxJTGLRi1iE@dNnrxcFctgV@EZWGpeKmqGLEV1sel0raKx9wtD77NHe/sFJTt0RSEI93NvPqc9f3E8oaC0s7dRbQ/vxwd6Dpy8gwrNHB3vPDz46@uTgxTNw98j58oqGhXBwiAaJmGmN/Zx8yr123@qGoRtTw@icT6fnb8hr0@yYUJfWFArlDF3iGR0oy0RflqsGd8/09NevdXdCL/L@B996/4P/4f1vf@f9b3/r/W9/7yeff@9bcP8I7u@w93f@baWAz598/i9@5/1v/TY4/me4/xDuH//k81//Orup/Y/g/q8xtz8K7lg4dnMA65d@8vl3f/iTz3/5@3D/q@D@/vX7V368/v7eNzffGO@7v3NzmO/8O7h/l8EKw37nt5gbvq@F/y0W7pe///7X/j37/0nwQ@Nvv/@1P8JHYPnn3/@T//r@G/9RVct/8m/ef/O777/5jfff/Pb7b/5T9f2v/xtFjj9@5/33fv8v/@B3//IP/mf6/xF9/u6H/N9//5//@f/@5//pz/8guH8M978H04///D9CP/2b3/8B/r/7@3/zhz/A///6r//m93/1b37pf6GG32CG/@df/Vv2/Ktf@S9//Zvf/ssff/2vf/XHf/0bv/@X/8cv/1@//l/@6n/8vb/6Z99Ax9/48V/@4S/9xTe@9Rff/Jd/8Y3PNzy/dePz8w9w//wfwOXD8/khcD6kXF/U5fOfKT9/F2wsU4F2Aq37F9//@i9AA/81Qt5/60d43BbuDf8fqQoN8yNm@/@BQb1eZvSRwQT3r77/1ncQRf8ToAj@Eb6@HVlWfJjl20sLoPU310T6xZ98/i9/SG0Jo9qgK0k4dJfVcjYD4k2mUgmG72CRCaL8wiq0CECQ0reRQq34fRtp2/sffP39D//p@x/8xvsf/BIO3kK@ktvLCcotK3QQsPAB4TBg8UPCYcDPIP1Ols7QCdnPwLb1WaGs2bZd@@yzz7jOpYTnuu9dks/gRz4LL8K88Nx34BX6oTseBCfg3nz1qo3LujE3SWHAJZW9Ay/cdQ8pCeqd7K6kqMzLuJS2WSxSAwetrLViWZcGg0wVfgQe1WrmIifstoD1o1EXnBEWSQmgbklE0XNaRtMhoJRn4UjVvifns6WMroMcm0W4WcoDZUKOrKCRWTZIchYs/aI7BJplqHFG2Hz@jHrPuBldIYZ/iZAy0Qix2b/GkSxll@iF378NjdQQxAtXl6mRK0Ay2eVqAWURCePSMsyFrpnTdPMVgiWYzbIzkL3BAClkwes@yAD1ehYj1lkWwcoK0ygTmpVstg7lxtgsTq5TRhCz@xQKxKxnj0knU5@xiFmE1wjRkeXQ6ZhXVD5brj@ABOuzBwRhIXAK9tWreqNcnzUQ3DuGnewse5/mCYHVs7PGO7DXKUyIxyUevIOslOvZbKOMCWIhWfXkOqySCrRwtOxZkg3qAN549GH3HiF3eKXMs4WSLUQYC43P7DI0BoTg4N/KZoLi0H9opHeGInyLJhWkQpj/LuWRdxnbjAEAriCIokjgxr0Iu@QeeM8YqCxNFl5ZBiFLWwRtAZEDwdmkLJel9ZulFkgfnM9d0zeIquZrIG7UCDq5PQ6/HEx3t8vc9gy3Vl6QgEWWa4ROSS44HcLkZY27uNSDEwrbOlmAU5HDECzNzBe@MLOIrO3tbS7R4DX@qUirRpKIe1ql50xw6yUKTlXCFys8Ohv00E1YVohfw/KR91//YSIvlxLcdhLXMJOEpUDuZNl9716G3AF80vfSjSNCVnPyToKB28lmeRUSajhZ7mUG0ZbIUkCXnDir0zXTLJfLESLWE@hHnj59GuSGOrysc1noT6qmoB2X7qbTaQJiiGJOzOWCt0jf1EEMDCL1Dd7iNmKUxOU2BaR5dHz37h3UNd3BVj0CCZoEm9nUfJl6ggNT1mVZ8/BMlpqvcGySgSjFPCEpWqtwpQkePkpB80xz7OQDayLhlUqq5XKShgSsi6lMuLuxqCBdYae86NltUiitWCE3cSvOGLJpaVylj45XsfylyoV06Ln/lOw/ffz44MnJpN0mHH65d@obnYnr9AzPS6Hf3pMHrAmqlWI60WwiVk6qKtI57qAqY1PMHj04PnpeJQxLQQWlaDlqdIE7wEtF4RKTyac7iWAzGI@fX3X45/isLlGRUitAg9OJBpfoGShYQZPDP9w17rE3vO/MSErO8XxOKaKgm8aFWsjHzztTgsrBmSYx6Np4dEbc2aEY4BoXQmxdCB0a5FjlmEFQqIFolXJoKDGDUipiALbhkmhc4/nBCYA@eUoUVRa5xmdkJmLWhAXXsOqWYQ/90TbuXORbMh8r/XZTzuFP1TR4KvliTimU2ltb1oWACbVoe7jALagLsF4IWOAvw0W4L3Pky@AEl7AgHG4sJcE8@9HTWrC1EjV2ptj@Sl4pQMdNc7hWEMDjJvELKFHiymIbl9j62td80mgcPHkgHB3ihMFsRML9hYLZF0cibRP9qWtQ3yEhffMTEz/CK/ZNb2Lpc@iFgJDEYrEYAKSjQ6I2VGplMfr4XPSoSxfMi5nOAdEccIm74cQIl7Cr1fo7JV/ijveq1XeaqnLgwGUk3NC4Ba2H7gbJSOxX8yBRTStLGS6h8Dy8NE3jaNsnXNXgCN38806u14WAxOYVuveHww896bP6chU/CDu7swyrySws@oAHGfoukUO/EvMLbCFVBjTifkfcu87VAmIg372r4QyQlpejYhKKBLKACtvW8hpWAriBazuRLwWrUzzPtxOcZfikXwdzogWPGuuHSoInaEM6pZVlLtFMQK/kmu1m/f/7X7vJtWf/eP@Almazzs2AuMXvwBnD0DdZ@XHcY@fp8v/06ThuvfE/fuo8fuqMHfjDUPUYKU9t@a/VVqw3/wOih8SlBmMR5@OZJxl@ebnA/aO/oGfTJs3WRXcCneINumu3qVTy7QPoMk3S3gnVjTcg9A47KU1Qz1udxwJLvhmcnm54hjUQ8bhfnd@ZNDRZ5XeCD5s0woiNfr3v9Ka4v6rWF03bNlw8l80i5PN8zbFRRXA9XHyEsSZ9wQ3r51R3DGfUhyJqnXNt3eL6Ytfpz0XPn1t4cM5y3HoSpJ5k6LGEbgA7jDO/u5qWr0KRxIkz2eXUQinbVGRgL/BWyjk1t2XslkrVvtizDN3dLVQL5Vwfz@QFS8O7Bbk6FD97/Oih70@ODXpQbzdfgQiopxU1Ku6Wq4UCtFiezzZpMu2m3BbZoCNsbQGZNvS@AG9cOfYEtdyGyH3TrdeTyV1NUQWlqsnlBbdEHOB8pDTycn5HgjeIaBKuSMOACDhFJCs70gSrD4wQRAdjF4yFHakLRhOMlR3JBOO0oSnyjjRltYg4a3CYmSziKoc1mRspF8FIUbUd21hw1ZyeMy8oaquDwWCRucguLZx@ITAbIH0h6LnuRWStCbFwVTLNCebSE1z0AdThRbDQXuXVQpmvNWtLe6nI19oL7t7Y6Js6HvpryRfXYxVh/GZQE5BQi3CLqus4frVrDBzXWAbUlGIYkGXoeoA8v4iSa8mY4sX15IqxQLOL61DyBX4RxQqzxS0WUJkM39DbXr7kEpnjT7RGAxrGRb6k5gv5gqoVi4WSCjxHJV8slKFS5aJcUFXohflKuVJaQC@QpHcJ@jVesn8R9o4q/R5RSq8yhdrNNkm/e2JaF2VNYP04la7BMJZ4xyXuHH@iNhqbZy1SwKN9ogqNulaogElDk6rRQU9VBVUTNEVQNPzfYlDx/@HhVfir@IRYmsqdoJq9J8A6AWdok0eorst3yImDH2wckvtGb0OI/ZFOzyTsu47n/R3C3NftU@b1wGS67SOvhzp@tdYbm/5oQ4gXkzFq6DPcfzAIB@MuZBCpJwtwHx6u5TjrApTIi2cbSvk4@poMIIN9TgaCHx999PAk9j452Nt/yBXJ/adPHlx5FYJABfLo4PAkspaYbxi1EIH4@YNHj65ag1f@6YvjwdRx8eYOn77ILx@REx555/JwrQaKnCmQ4IFWKocAC0m2QAwLDQqHB6Xu5ivkbmAsFJdGGY2fsvP8phcd3GGqHarcSXjIX6e6QroG6TFFjDjHRJUkB5KiUqpw3ITYzjkpyaTvWJbuEmcw2ALHkY4Hlg2UfywLWyImfe64Vv/c7BtbwNNAGhUQIwc0E9xDADKe9qiOH@BeUeU@DII2wbXbrjU1yHRCNjrCC53Q6JrDEQzZ504YgOvqOoH7i14Q34hf/s0OPkuDul3zsa4H5xJcJcHz@zz/UPf1mmuUXsrV6jMXRm5vaDQOZtBaoe/o7jxXzmm8zx@Sqv0yow5xBdByJiisepNmZgqc@dYWSNx/9Zs/@ts//tVdtSXvyzh3@fhRXp0Dd6FItW79Hcj@4@5l4yXZzTv3CEFOHgU/sWMkysN6FSgfCj8EhRtC5ZdAxhGpqKxWyoVyRVPLuXKlnC8oxUIhp6g5pVQuVQCKrJSVYrlQUXLlfAU4m3wFfAsgszIJSQpFIilTBbB2z5r2jR0qbYsjEKvZgj55m9LTJKFH9inhDYjDczgT4lMNERmzDuMnUWSilQhA1EmPJA4P9@XDQ56/jxbcz7Qv83wfLYWyLJfu87xBffbLyKXxDotTRm3HvM8ssnwfKmLKAOCHgnh@hJaDIs5Q87yJlv29w0NMZ4AWFeNDsFPmwyxWaClBMBstILdRAG8iaBBsj6WTpxk9QAsmiT6HzGcf/Hj@ozA76HPMgjEAD8OS7u3x/BGz7O2hzz4tdoFl9Cto2aMXz7tggf7B80MwDF3omTzfBSP2Ep7vgak318FtDCb8lozt6zw/Z@hBBPH8jIbWe6c83wndMZlPgtwUELtValFYqe9RSwV/PK@GmcZgWmTReD4fWfJQtocPP9FHft8YsmvusncPSvrwoaabs@nBYfejj7rDYded7x18dIxe@/sPgRmZT93usBtE7HbgciDW/kNVPx3Pr15Q6qNOp6pba72@0unkdfuKV2feMTCHEOsN5Cy4hpjQuLMPXvsPO/f0dRszKMAOEogxvLt43R/D@77eZV7hRb3oe9bt8jVs/pLUSnEog@AeC@yOp0Bw7dxY77lODe2zOpFzyNfMm0W5XaMeZAyyhFxboP8ghU8dZxvTF/PmrC6367N6KdgJOUjxrZlaMPnc1nhXqRSqW/quouazsyoqqXEGSZIUlF2SUu5m3pLUk/SuCnLFFt/a3RX4ptLeLZZeIhGq4mNXVcrVvKySNLNqpSrEkZMyIfhIN0vt3VKhuoxcKmV1Sa2WSsC7AX584AC6OOXXIanUuaGfptOYdTqtBOWhBSdzWmizNkjNcrM6yySZp2uzulJjH1Qg8hVoqVQfv94z7aHSdsKADgHgbFeu4q6eFK9UyjzkQZJS6XREAyUwLSfpPv3qyenJyWeUTWwEc17PXAOJWS2wfvRwXzx6GtrwyzviIbKvjivuIxFb8WF8bOh0AkKJ@BAGXhAZQzc8G@w6lnhA97MCDxx6hMr/xEALvnjycAXO85FzzlJG1So1qkrZ7hkEP0xk9oleb4BJ75MUzRXR0@d0yO80GvVOfUy1j0ARw1hfIfSrPUswRx7Le6TwhUa/wPOygUenLi9g2JklZgCnUyeC8mrs9F@p2V6tj98jul@/j5FrHXh3a0bdcF3H5UHe42uDXbs@tT19YDwzXFRldPR0GxgQPESbGhAjvU1aBxh6H@WWhdBwib3M2ZPpOKULjW561QmnfiMHRE7qq2GhL@i57k6d5xe1QZ2kXkLQN2B3t0mqL95P7@ZrgKf7pJMGJ/nV4NWAqKSYr1HxJIWwoGdR/GC5dZKuN74CLwb7tFqF3AQVfQpQMTEAbPapB4SemItar26RlEBmJE2RlK8N602MfomPHQEGeEFoXra5hiB8yjWg@9bmCb3uTbv0U3ZE7iqqXKzNwE0p5WsjqF795azm1idT16hZYA3mgdkRdr0GSAXcAZi3l6n3v/D19I5QqDO3GgV1idxBR@zUZzUblWNDw6hrdfDINvNyrlAGxqFQygELoBZzSjGn5fI5oYSuMP7nCjlwBLkImJKUleIJ4XPyTBaVnGIouZT8yuy/SudOU8DrUKSRdM53DuzpmIALVBW2TWqFN6Anq2YskNf6DtF3BNpYgWrUsGCA9RGZmLkRgjo2dIvGSKcFomVS1nYKw2yfTCcHzXa1ejCbfBW8UsKb3WK2JGffptO11Fa67hlvuEaNayCBoaWebEHLDabIiTcdN6GWwaSU1Gqz2cUiluScJmtQOrNzOdzhG3w7J28VFaiiBZ1hUgijG/EpYmSAlm6TDvLrlgFVp1TUGifS6VqtrAoVqZApyGzOmMXkJgGBQ0ySVIsP1TWkksmSmkymkzVcEdvig7UNoGmUniWBwCbvKrs88GZ8la@oGGBJHOmJfDnMHXBnCw65SZIHcfiCW1wsdkB@/xL3HA9a76gv8Vd6@XjvKf6@BE4VsJZfPn7x9MXTQ45IdDO12EnUtmpirVMDiyA27nGJKiFASluBMjlpi5Avuk07u9N4yd4tPN8DcDn6xYsmadPtk4aJwh75BBWV7JIkFEJ3x01V1dpNtQRjIZDTMKiqKjXIRSeBJ4jEBtTG7ALyt5Nt4Bnfr5D5XM8K4QzB3WpjmN2W1XnirMMXKxo7otpQ5FOylbybIcDeCCRxdrrVUDPZ5LOqlk0@SGr5xFmqtd3IKvOkRDJZdT7AfR@4f0BKQjjVyNzRMskX2Wp5mKsqWXyq8KwmibCVuNfJ3UtXPI7WCUlcmbLYq@8Nj/dqoW2/UVbnwdnkxMsOXy4FWWxtA8rU7MvV2A0YgF/iOgvu8EzWkomLJEkkF8lFM9nmEvfoCWiVnYAmiegMNO68CFYOtXyRpBOVdGArVRJeKlq2@1LyXiKJq2NVz3uXoK0qPFb6lVcqNOiE7YQOIAXi9BsMuIUCrgslpFcT72tqWXt89NR@4B4aXKK1dbnl4IJeOOEM1zv7468SMgEUJ0mrnpjV88ExDqXREJQdFXU@lkgVxpSBUhTkywbrNQ3qUVTB5/0vfD8/2ymDXZUVsKtqIas2GkoGmJXE5P3nv4fauy4OPtl7RJK4kvO3f/xDtfS3f/yv6UbR5IKu7qhaKQEh0agUS4mLi8nFxQIu5ldItBPX9se0AT@SoldKGRFKI5V1MHSkBMMjMFUlJZ3whESwPbhYEFIpRVLTGa0sp8HnMtDOl1LlMljD1VHqxBcLfDpxcGwWVOXezi6UbFfLq7UtqEslOs1Oot@O4VWgcsqPX10SApZeoz8cmio1SRKpvhN23hFhh7zDhcl3whZ5VW/g/h4Fz8CHa3EZPFuLS9vJRlbKJAkIY6TRXNQW7SxdzaOy7cuM3bqCh9YWHtxadcrY8DMyHv0ZBrVSBw@soc3IvPb4VCYtSf0@1RaJi6WC0EiwHtIxSKEBTSUjQS4z4VIc@wlCK/3@F35dVYt/@8e/ctm57HymgiBbqRQVNfHTn@5M7aln9Bs/hYg36GoKhVHKgqJSJTREQixhuljNIFZkEHsgP09tZNhZ@FCkRSGWAHdjDm2jT0Va7gw5MlqjHaYutJ@iwTKoyiVHGX6qni9d47iQGWYMvTvs5SgMkkHV8c12mrvgvoxeMOATEApq3JeXoMBhDEO80@t41tSd0ANvKRpPaefIXYgCKXwZVbFuURU0wWghANWUMtejsix7FGuUeyNjw/NQsSsMdNyXIUrwfQ1rTiY6akvCkKYNw5OIQWg@qUe/CWm3IW2LRehQ1xQtPQuQIyx3LJINfD73ZWBYKBZM4GOIuQMBakBOvgwIgDKkAsBmm@wQLU0uzGy2ttQauyBQ6XgATA81tXAYDaH1UTNQGLmG4cAJ5Av8oju2i6CGgY2MOYZAGAy2c6UOEgpGpzZkDakqpQ8GBbCo2sIULRq5e3eZq3rd7KcJLRHCPzUnOCNH68Fen1cAFop6d/pVPkdQH28tdI2aHWA8S7MLrU5ginhrsaiER@uC4@D/wY0WW@SVqqIeNSxAUF@sV/QAZRAZ0c7qsEd26kRRS2kSZb4Hee/RTFF9GZH82prdEdXPQs8F5PCnifB7iUCsTuKznEG7vaqqhwA7P8WP1aHCRkYMAhU7TCUjEr0jP4wdxYKimBYNPTBdEKXo5ppQG2xKU9IYbak9l@aDnn1R8wSPoBTS@KKxMDSBt45aTYN0tqg2tp4DFepNHJuqQaVq2vAUELQIoFGBBkmW7al9jh83DeqGRo7nyKPaI7HlY46pWlcH9V3RuLhZpeuC0B3iJkeMoUh64z5RKyRFGxrVdGlH4NI0Es1wFzhyxHHXMsaQpeeGQY@delVJGgKTNu1SdZ@PTWhXo0MTRh7bkx4wBEvn5qkpneBXBgRngKdTmfKkBPJ12P3YbpdAtablOKfEMk8NNnmdWlE95RGQSYCtzgFmlzcgtorbsVQthzMlSo6FgrsErxIzlnOxuFupefr6W1O2Uh2s0Us6gplQK5Zxptsx/NLrkguEcW/uhcrrqAo2sIsRyTUCtVX1JCqkifSxcYEavjrVACfiosgkxSf4UH0dGrmJa5wRFKs5HGOAaPZCRVDYi6G0X6YDAO170LNQq63vVlF9GeTE7ad60PUCAm@TO0RTOQzIdAsGegABBlZ9fRU6@EFULIfn96FiRLoSgHQFeue4D36oOCdofhg/bN1ophqHl82bbAXgcNChadUJ6xahpRCzYO/A9kyLvgWeRcjhmpxspfgsgM3yaZ6BjuJfjc5aO0dpSZVch5QjCCFANUChrIKOJAfVlsa@QsqBx33dY5@qCnTenp@fi1QR89Q1RcPDL3N6jq1b0mRoAifsSL4xnkiGB13XNXvSJIS7NAnsg7ziZDTZnSE/W6/cnbM3xw28erBtLZUceEkcHM/ww5PDMVXaiNoSPdqgDk360dpeKthFx9qf2s5dhO2viu1PKCcXCIQQBDPLzXO9HADLdXunucF5vxZ4nNEOCcChFo3QEdWju6Fl7IUmczKIQjg@0tHIq2ud0kVjgMSzKeVl0qyEYch5aA3sExN3rNrGOdlzXX2eov5pDI0NODWnbA@Zw7BPfcCIn/G4YLq6zVlz3l6JPouiw6AW7cNwUSMjd3EzUKa4Hf1nzH8G/jPmP1smGibbnLUZS4ZOCywOtnrcehuGRDDzMMyCKTlf@lDIwIcThYHAkPMVtwXcvTqNHeKb2aAe62HDgDYxAYQbKan5stVstW3POM@0s9IQGjtPEQE1DqCbbYrT835kRuxbZ9bE8VacbNTfDKNSkG906o2C1sDaCpYxqiDaMBi@TFS5OxwHG0YYQxAUGCAgHwaeyBrs@SkzXYu@FEA9oeE0@SWOWcaaQWbalPsKvAI3YJcY6v/f7r5tvY0cSfNafAqYkouZVvIk27JNmSpTEmWzy5Y8kmy3V1axUmRSyjJPxaQOLNv9ze7FvsDu/T7Cvsq8w1ztU/TGHwFkInmQ5Kqe6f22ui1mJoBAIBAIBIBAhBDWBnRiAcL3uEmEJqUoM3IkDrORDh9GA8pj8uY5dGwPrh9zJzmi5NRQEVmzwZ1kYZXPGzSJ7FBXq9NNMenUFcdTSVYzv@n@t9G/993od2hczMeeGVYmjI2MPVRgo0sqhB4uTFW1WbX6lTAoPvC7wYhmrrrop3q2pmoeFM0yQ@pBE6KrcNw6d6zOb7nSP3wLOtvPVmJWmFSr1MRJVYaljAtDUiF4XCzSxSaGEXR5ESAEozS3WKCLXdvFrqtVERzqekGxKwvJa0byWopI7usFSJ7oYrR6apjpBd1zQtopjIizBK8s0yipQcOsivzLAOf0v8ItLc4tdJ2JzGEu0DwEFRt81jqZW/uxhbQltKYAgBFnAJAW4l90x5XMtMAr5@O3WEYJKY2MkjfNBiIriMFYBG@I63YnZjJeA5PCn13leYDGbnb1OJMt894z/leSf1nPfDT/yrMfS@mc5fTHkjf1v/@QjyegrDVALe2jXHoEgYyVzLu@9nls6xzLqnZBCxzS6k6vBsqZo2zT9@KFLlo87Q5Oiz0f9jYI9C5fC8OJa9YPOL1RL4aDsT8ePHpUkUVTyGw3r35ZM4Rn/QHiQ1rhG0jXaw@CqJ8bU6e2Bmf9MAo8Bc@6nwO97Ah0QJmMrSfrx0GUyWjTL1nGArTwFVTdZjPsh@Nm04H9pVuJLxOwOSbYM5fLYP1LT1Z5Ek8a6P7QGZz@GrTG7u0wEYtEFzsKW5@d/aFOhM@WmiIZ1iL9n1LPSYNR0SBZOXKcA6jSp2OHowKdD3qDM9L6LqICdmAzU@AbCWwg5A@HjIunfCxpK1ZEGh4lTsvzXV30p@8uqn5ac3w3Lr@WBpAihqdG0zQGZUdzqmsurE6KmfoOvx/fQxvfw5vx5VX4NM6yNK9K4vdV/dBJIFDGBI2Ht6OBppPcas@gk0Il/gy9SgrcGcU227O1gWmNstZ09kKH@MOL3yJ6ixF/v4j@N3egKV6/a/f5NOzV4YTkTQ@21eJvKTKHsA5lb7iQPbPVxay9c8e6KC@iqe9ChSA1lgVXHy7aaWAi/loUhxkygG/heZiQzfA925VVJXEOTqNLT31eW9xFO8120PUnQdvROT0LrmnxAS3YWF7dreEQdCz0BrLWc2jucuNUmsZBdMlUWcAyvnfpuovZSrKEMffwTjlj2FhMP6TPiGZs8VVlt5rWAbncMrZjL0NsfyLunEQB6Uo8Vy1HZf6RnoQPl9sJQnSQ2bPsJdW6N4nPAydu0h1mhDhvId1kOOk3EOFcbbYPv49Et7eUOtcqVDW9nEnHv5rf4@FNPW5xheFJOW66G0vexnR35jmL1QRYIsK2v28KmYEMy5FWy7Ehypcbe2zQn5EJ@Mb7dP0Fs0pzjkCNS7KkG4e83Gb9ws1gZdygX2w4vadfADwLxk1hKNM27GnpEOmKU3r@0NJa9BdS0gmKRUUhuUbDypUxz5T9y7e4ztbCOlszdbZSdcYjIF2llSnTSlWpewHdc1MXdIPOeIF0RhLWzvRzk9im//oDf4Tdii@5MFcJPZW7zFVIIOeCXKXukFDOtXOVHX6IcpVDfvicq/xED8nYyn3NVcywQIYRvfLDC3zXIhzvrVxl23G/Zcb@5yAy9RZylbhPKc@P8soUIVKg3aQ14oitP9DNHI8CmthYqfQUOCbysHzifRiP/5Xo/xLRjmNdIRF7nA84s1pV5dSkYc0YUg9NGyaWypyRXNGzeX1/ly2v4iyoZpXWeHYZBk9q@HIuLYwEMaTyiQb9EoKQm5X5GClrJrsjOrp24lDu5HT9EveU9YG2w@nHlPkkqYTDGOrypr/SIKQD74YnCi/CcwYdUx1jhDNZdw5aIOovuRsahb5O46J73@4h3utOZyJs8yaL9BKDtWQ66XB8OMeRYwfDNJNwKm4FhHYZ3pSTQQnunSrGUkGPzAXJ/Fm3DILBHvzuTc2xygG1lAhC4nHpREZZPC@wLEZSIussTVUGH6FgyRwa4UHrM4eI3NGPnE/EjcdzxaJpyJSVKllypcUkFS7AJ92FP5ba48VrHZ7qvm/5akpeY6/FAQCrZFyLyNfBd@jvA9HfjUJtiDBVwTzFev5UOqte3zjLTmHeTaqd7UAkemrHnascxTUkJKfVgaWZ38RrMyo@TD5EyZdKY@hT2r4hW7wmuIVu02sLgQUtYXSZ/vh5jT5@XltMqFmNpHtZMEpLATVpONLwGNOkaTfjKg2f18VI4f1tv/vdHTxKd7DdeYDHDRhNkVxG@eiiz1YuydgmsS1fIFLLFSWCnI9L425OPpK456Pb@NiWPuw3D3b2915/pEn3yZMnrp6jJwl@GLXYa43ncYHMZtzxfDBn2bLmIY4bDruxHR@dD0bje5/62RlZIsKalAG4ZjHsp8e4q2WZJc@nxi6Vk7wWRTWsz8kw8FNSCaqOjyk71HQdE0GCsfPA10CMekv09ni15nLEsmaz7/dgz4/pq9mE8VKzqWcxdI05EXf/vnyveBGNOKi1hNu7ymTYiYra2VcfXtWO1NGrutp9t/2T@rj/Tn2o7R3B78Xbd1uvG9uK/tX3DusqkzLBQ2hSLCiJrjtBK@Bo22ul0iPFkLcHw4nIHWfble@Hfk@9GrQCHFM9j/zei3N5KfSD8aaUqtNydII9zJBD0fbCMewtOHYqLWOh3LT5JiNuHijKe0pr2h7WvL1BO@yElDeDte8wDCJz@U11Q@pBkrfmurgnShLCpLLpEIc/hgXWFRX3KT/ObgiML/ZXIDFySFzVdkFpwsX/fTcFj@oHbw4VnK1s7@/tNI4a@3uHanf/gF7ffmzsvSR6Ng6PDhpb75DEGd/s7zR2G9s1/iAIlAoKXlB@vYjGN6JQQHamSuszTr4LQ@r@@C296w0NXl35fKczUrmLPqRP6HfD34N2biNzEUF9wT1SPipQzkrt4OV7mvNV8BtOOM1RMNsfZN9FHLp3paSec200WDZpvG3o4UrTXr7s8nlEb6IQvSvYYJcnDj97ygBnI552GKjsNmxUsPctnlF4LBvQVNE9gg1QxmClqjjqXi7nPWeQm1RbqzuAt1@pTYwI9QuKvjCmJhsZppi2lQFQ3Kxo9LEfVN6IPxDf04c1Xe14JBnUw/iDZFCP5ANU0QZsR9RjneNivH8B8azW5cOvveEuHwurJ/GHLZ9XsU81TtJv3KW@iqOWwk9Ml2Mryi4Px38WD0EoEnF@xB3sdmVgBBLxlmSiHCWybRvlzJKw6eCoQZu9SSR5pBI3wE7I74wj5VTdgjqCcVDQDyWq5VnX74sJVGK6w7ynnsKJWFVfGQ/jaJB8V2U4YAZEJNo0HnG5Ha0VBnctRyW3Zmr0tY0kR2Q2Jmi3IbA1g8AfAUOA8qmVTotnKr5mCzCDjmZlJxoQR2Lf9m92fmLn9kUrSBXQVlvOr@Hvv7uayF5qnWTsFBk76qLfgxGplXyU2RmMaIyzWOX4eZCCrfPBcBxKHzrpFvCJE09zlBsTG9X2S3UzVRvoMF1jf9C3Kj0lLl5Q6ykx5V1qZY6Xs/NYfCWB1YnzaRIWuzug458OLgPr7MzDIdJVgO0XUoT5rBybn5MxYyL6ZyaRHX9TiMf8tLq5s/Up/7dfPARlFrEgMdGN0SH@EWOiLhoefM7HBosj6F16pJlgmtHFKUprGzwtLTHKDTBaB56HtK570dyI08TcePY77vFMf@ePX79WpVQekkkk8kV07iTSzVPHpkqPy5wobQJiyU5ClmS9Y754DDOW1y9wdwe9sEEU6UOOYN0@FapSixDTutOLDkkWHTFcd3cM31WbbFFhFEnxJWH3R/FnZ6u6uukWE4MSZZHTMSLaM5DLrmuZpfB8NQNu52ZwJL/vDu7pjdjJ9PBd0HZuhPZduOVXF8OSacmCdXewf7sBrExufwgstd1bDFgmyVloMafHzOmtLMfWtDfX@MtM3/HYIzCYe7GDEgO1arvo8xG18ZrvSAHXBpMoRIdHO/WDA5WV9QmVJbmHJUNbi0HAvqfeJta2YZ@FXSFWmuLFcqw8mS8pizbz302DeS7xFogKrYN4mh6xsIjv4dCC7lqknp5ZWIVg63sWiIZyaey@GBkUHWvA32gNSMgmnWY1MDO3mcsy@YSRbQSu6eaJbmzb8LOFtczdiMM9mtiAbJsg/ww3S@b33wfRjyumHlGw4MMJDW6TJk3zDa0TDqniIWUsFNI9eEO3mC6Fkb0o2MuGdjD8KqU17D/PUMxIooSLLmyJda0ca9REP14xag4bJGIa8GHpqRPFopkSjIjnL8/tDnWTSc9JT0GkZCIy8wubK6j4yTc9hTE14nmyGivk9lhbYWyODZYn2J3VsDcWZ7oPW@j1afEwXRVJ2xuryv9jqpJZIlWTofncxphEgrz@@PHD22BPt8IUz/9Z2DKHTMvPcW9I6/sEZDSJeHufOLex55n0hAFuIJ2Y1psBM1WQVJ05c0qq7TwZ2fgRLrIvRMgg5gSCXU/X6qrrKdzmQ5cZyYbOWWbaYA3huKEyamao/@3m6iCQb63v3vfXJ4MNmWA6@A1W@W8GoyhIbuVZvmWsT7iEn/4WjEZ9zib3mXqA4vA1phsv2/FtOzF4lVYhkc/b7JZ09O0kMbv1zF4DV8LbiwXEt8fu3sb09l6@vGE3dbfxuq4esGfVTmovMjvKupbsuRf2b0KAZTDvS2D64Dt896MK/SMcPAOSyMS3@RymjXsrbkwR0pqPOZSYNgvVsrU83fudqOX34Y3Ey96PVNb7gQryLmx9f9edt7Ne2kiVJ@SiYd@hUl42X8hyUfqGDV1ASoOQ3sR3a8LCTQ1jKYnrNWcD2EfhYCu4lt0ztpz0i@WnpfVnGW5d3xt7veNnJ96DVjWraPL1@73oYnTV/nw2OL/sqK4a/np63Zr8/ptSjx/BYbta@0EccpfXq0V2PvxEwZf7sxJzrkbwR3YujnjrBQlErVROJevwjXvK5QdeNFdwQ2KKS9WDnuFCXLEbV3vH6yfVfrW00Tvun2zgkt94tTpeLa86@PADzaIkY@Rk/nh8gjnV3nUN@pcKDmM5zLG@GqL4agh9eeOPwsHr2t7L1G4cFABsgWlbb95Ql9j2S7Bmw92TQj@4cvQ2mafAsRkoSJklvhVUxnV33k/Gdkw7JMyoVzzSZqNr/jtxM0ulwsVwPOAU410SrKW@hl8zS@YaU4l3FCjLcWh8UOJ@AcFJ8jg4GJKvE7GizpdFXSvj7qRrgThGSRaH2U/ZLO4UAlF9l@v4JBMVAr91DiS6pFZ/5WK4m4w3YrWowLt4MOXwR3xhonSCRxyA0M@QTxtQBWvuEV/7yFDz8V7Gg3zhPaox35NhA/kMa4pIgfm3@sL3m7j8cyKAEH5JdK6C3uLUmhcpknJ3kDcX4IstvfDHMQOuVUqnLKGxgC31VRPgbCnONEK1mkz0fekK5BRa0X@6Bfkyv800I87vSnYmCZ9T67cItOQu5aRN/HSTYo5VLG@KmcwWKZZupQZ2umh59CagYTVR20G3S0gLLZYScuCR7/fq@lfj@qNj1HkSIy/p@Zn0fCq9IOmCVJKrQBN8kqliZ8ouf0nyfVPZJJs3U1dVsfJSoJ5uFUglSfJu3JQ3KowHzTDJvBl3pXBlnPA8lZC3Un6e0/uSci9VJmbwOP1Y0jV/r@mej7FM5X2Rrh@/Gd1BARvPaluTKS4t9MPujzJpxSlgsyxRUykpzjFYlRlUVX0HU4sT0uCwz8/DdrOaQFktG4nDYya7@fxFtqCVjB@daTTkFuPMwJozRiwqcZ2rTLhrvrBI9XDyPQsEwwSjKTNyN03hiS48scAi1z1TrdyCnBng1LTpIV7Fvciv@GMGexo5k295fuKSYH4tjZfbzWkCsdC9l51PprQ0wXUR@agbdcMsktQ9mYY4X0jsWbvAcZ2B3MHuYBv8XiwnbEFhJMUM3eMUTekkQ9mw76IuROK3zN@LDzIvfdKxh93gWtWwzPD5FlYmdcF9HETjCA6o2DVOdDEcdnHqyArfFV@h1tEg1h7juCWBaM3shUwDlj2S38OTvpBOhQpqH5CvYCCSJEQXZ2e4TIYbsIMriFbsuITjQqbWn8iGBo2Zh2tyzTxQcL7BArgbntlISM/J6AGlo6HfCgoZ0tEi0n4y0tROqEMX83467o3AzxlNaZVM5l8uwtbn7Zc4z31SLj0sWyS71MfBpcLDR8kFKyKSSViD58LH5UeZjHU23JKz4TwAeuo1Jvr3xJvBZdDvB5kazRicMSKlNQpGl0G7kMkcBPEhMOCClXEyiXvYg4tRSzZ3SOnyiRlxSzjy5DiMOAy/mJ/luLjFZ2VeBodWyWkzdfVl2AYBzY2TzgCnw3xgATcBQg8U6gVjIsoDV6VR4rNnjQvrLj1sRBE14OfEOpuIydAfjMMW9QzvZGW6BEqOQZLK@u0pTKi@VtfH5eDCPARwPSahgEHAHCXdhENGH5p/Fw5KN8ycsfumZ4ok/QY8Vmi4B6OQpG9CYO4VLmbhTh189KpxqA73d48@1A7qip7fHuy/b@zUd9TWRz7jxkE5OwpWr/Zfk3SJT9Pl1HyfPmRrh1QyywmZ2t5HVf/r24P64aHaP1CNN29fNwgagT@o7R016oeeauxtv363w6fvBEHt7R@p1403jSPKdrTvca2mWCYpp/Z31Zv6wfYreq1tNV43jj5yjbuNoz1UhlP9mnpbOzhqbL97XTtQb98dvN0/rCs0LLPTONx@XWu8qe8UqH6qU9Xf1/eO1OGr2uvXUw3d/7BXP1BsJGC1cqtOWNa2aAmLmridO42D@vYRGpQ8bRPxCMHXnjp8W99u4KH@1zo1p3bw0dNAD@v/8o4yUaLaqb2pvaTGZZxbqEL9sv3uoA63SaDE4butw6PG0bujunq5v7/DtD6sH7xvbNcPN1Tm9f4hE@zdYd2jOo5qXDXBIGpROj1vvTtsMN0ae0c0Z7x7C3sHlzr5AxGGsKxR0R0mMMwg0Foi0v7BR0AFHbgDPPXhVZ2@H4CmTK0aqACLiu0jOxtVSEQ8spup9uovXzde1ve260jeB5gPjcO6Sx3WOESGBgwyPhLrUKXvuNXoJ8JLHolZM4ZzPe5O1dhVtZ33DWCucxMHHDY0tzDZtl9pmhfgI9jaRAkH2DPwe/bGSmf202UAN5izOzLz92hij0nb@zt1mpG1k6tskvCOZp2nU66U7DSaaeJEek25rGkHpxdnzbDfGeCOaVxMNj560ZmH6FsuYgZ9ytwQ/E7vr3CB5eVm832tSQvdw2bT9e5SMoXGbSX0NvhNuVzdRsSUwMobGz@VitD9eYpQmz/og0421MMBBHIK9X8Q0ze/F7iqWGwHuhgu7wOw2TqK5NjkHEcpJBr5siOCHSVV8s4Ev4eaHbigY8AXWk3sk8IykjMNIvrT/5q8yORgfSDpLNtdxSIWsYxG@HtgqpFK2CUC/9EeCcIOV1mIguDzmVOyq8Oav3A2GLQd1zVlOO@Y1oFnjntL8dPgbKp4fro8I8vHzjpyQmTW3azCxOfPmmRK90thxC1z8Kc55h/XYCM@H7BrylXxZrXetHR@kOKwSPKUdm2B6xXcydD53tT@2viA1Vxp7dHG1PdX8XcZW7AXhMtcmvCOudwJ/7w6kQw0wNgXB5Ek1B4yikWrjLE3iTNfUcZzZLoK27D8obn6POB5nUhCiuyF37XrxGw8Cq9t7EkOvzyovdl6t7tLohPYPnr6@Mn6RiZ2u/VXT34/oh72actex4Y0j5OexknWKNkmxYdHiuVhPGF/ZuBiERnhYN50Gn@En4fYbiNtyQRBhuZGiPzVh4leNgAdsoodcNzLGH6dOzI1AzipprpoTc@/ZhXfJ12JeUAbs3Qn3GvX@APY8fA3QzxukGYgzWLs5Zc4l1YXLPeyu8ZUlBc37LgHWQpZw8fixi2mAW91sf0sbtfym@ZtqxcjMWXEeOVu55KExL1pLJSxq@jLyH7Lfkb0BjB7D6Mvf9X8Ro8ftYM7dnfnR@Pa@JDIuBuXxD51shmtG32sIZ8g4Aecqpmanivs8rsaKR57ejs5dgxijQZGBcFuYOObBrwR@xGZrpItYF/kXPVFOBXOOwBnQ3OsfifOndccDWXD@A/R78YrhRJYsZMTodpVXEfGZPkY@7Ew5EyR6U/Rg@H/E2kyB/5zWnES9IRalhPAO1GSoQqtaPnKRAmvzEGDdbqRUNP@9DEB883umPO4Yfr05lru1xAJdO9MzIeP7Paw48whAJgcGxv2@I1N0s59Wjq9yLq6OM5J@q3e0FF6rjBTxQzc/PqJx2qXZ85W8OIqV/aarApfU1H1QhZupzzqack0tZRX96OsgHON/4/iA94AiQc8c@m5WK1Oc1ZJjzIjB7SrJWvCaccek0gt/bbw1O6BslxkpmS/PvkyhCLQm8Bntp0c@WSgxDw37XGRZ2J1xF7w4Lkcy2RMPtpl3SkbYnYDwLnf5s0QBEcZX2GC6Ap0dtWXQFPOfTYUQSWJ1WHiZxDi1i0QaXlavYqx551JcGiM/bu@uM0PZFfL5CiIgw@NoX1dvqDe@BNCuXu3ZguLFR8cDjzYLqIy2ZbQ5REIpjUYjEh19NFuwtELJ25BfdCbDkE/uhhp/4U0n4UjvSNhlH6qBmqTrN55mhFv9YxaFI5xW6FdYP7gJvUCWIiKe5Lr/LpyiHkNj26aTcfwerWsnOdJynOiCbslZSI@V@sIhsu5hKDaZWjAFAyjeHHBNptcD84d4uF3NRh9xtwPFajfDtqxZ1ILJO8FSic1@uzjsTWWpg8HEe9oUFdgBySmRFk20mJDVZqjn2h20nZN2cQ7JnyXcku@v56YSY21FFWUMK6unZhvPU@dCSqtadegsbPQ8tpjRmXeguvbwsUYewtNH1ur7Kd@LFIqokRU7xvVEU8iN@Onj3jSm/zV@xFGD33BGbdWQYEwdFacq87KOcYPNgUfwmDUtvdESZNp@0Nsv/HSZ9BnXjRbh9rtX8sfR8GEVgCtYnhdZBhN5y@D835ze9D1z8JB6NM6Da7mr0Xi4XHCj@iws9HgKuIYRxJs08rUniTP4l9G3LDhPT6X3LBcc0XjYOjYZgrj0aR2Lm4ieOccRoBJOF7m7@G0j7S4zKPHSaFM@v4p2@OV3Y2FZR@W5xWWE30A0AJuc8qCQu6QjvliknX5dGMmw@lNGSwcT1Ve@e4Ci70Uxs@IRHwMk8LYIDNjlmA3AiuzhRgft6@9NvsgHMHRUrATIBRP5PBnz0egdZIiP8JSoKLKT0tWUTlFuYYfQjxMFpN77ck/GXtC4E@gX344j1vmMQKLuI7xthTJekV7GSVc2DwwZBnNkpikWHgW9q3rhxzo4noaajp5sogabPlDSpF2szfDlRiRDi18EIrPaZLIaU5cTCo5lXPZbwdUkNrYKS1m2OA2@1ke/DjElZ0zCKZtDdmxkF5EqhZRCZGhp8xrbZTFp/LtI2Zt7a69NkXA6jyTMyv4uZM1mgvfQAllfsWx1mBEwjg7RT1t6pGLxoNh7o7UWyg75npmm0frluveaggszFalyfJBm0lbneBxspGZxmeKadIUY0sz4iEsX/k5ZvNpIl5Xmxhv1ebkFjosolliNxVPKnF/t2XsY1K8hEWvmWjiIcW4w0npRvz9uEkNby6WIBqmLK@aLDGaEBnNiTxaoKbIFFPp7hRi7tO4T9GjTZRDvW2ind0/C4k6bSRnXJ6apJSTS9ATjttxaZPk0rAD4wu4iRMNNxZSscJ57U34KK@cP4WTYSQIQGjFQT7Zh5Id3KSzpviIowN0nCashcqQRPS0aVs4xE7/Y4KxV369uaMtHpqTfPlkQyBdx5BoVcG5boJk7pvT63HzmqHMkIKG@BxSxC2akU3nd2/Vn20L5SMIUpqTtaVvyUNjXLVK2NAfO6l5DR04qUqXTI2o9EBosmigsUCrlLNuIMtVaH/hSDge1g16GNECQj47@FnVJeDOe70UUxtFrtsTZHE1uWW0uSq/KUUShpJ3kF8PRVF1eeFKAALBmMpXywQBbk0ZexwKsOsdm/NSiOo@ooLVMoYlfWSvqImd55x0EFVnePTYylGal@OZDSM/FwgpFvPzJIiQzjI/SwKFJrq5uFg5nsxvT5KDFGLD@0Jx6grdK2kaxj0nBOTg2SU3kSjHZeWVNAdz4qPHbiox5m9OfVayUkvTqUSfGMPjfHk69WkplZqqdm0tXTRVkujh2rWmEokUro1wLBX@3H98NcV2eR7bhFqLjJSWoe2zEdycVpm0biv8GqnnfCnb6BgGnn0z3Cy/mhJiJeWU/WYH7CrHRwbw3f6nW2ssUw0mOlYA@6Uzl10cWRCyxprFVI9mYaVrPO3FDgrMmnbQUe@PdndTbl9PJ8bQqBeMHpdKJTDxqe383thWYyspHBTTuYudi263OLz6y@j9aZFlfxBwSICKWUEH1CU0KKLCYHQmkSGAA2VF7ry@yIq1/kWnY4dgwAklOo@6TXJqbwiKJ6AwNnp5f8QbQAxST7C/oIFo3y8qHn1XviiaGoo5hqLSMAm@zJrTMyIPPnRgnx2fVDEwCGZjzUTzllvd/IIZBJFNuLPYfbH7JTFPzr4Kut2Bpz4gSjI8BSx9my6wu2sXKEkWnDDy7d6LiP3Reiq4DLvWvWJksXkd4MzEZOJMGL/w8I1/EJzVr4dO9vjnLE0r1ORVNHMV/qk9lT3LutpZ/B3ACh8S2nfK3fOHTovpNJ2Zpno9gpMnwuhh2Zu79kllcXlPTNPs9twg6nx0C@ysgZrusi5gfNlz93JLFmSPiZv9dF3ugIYlgaFxgs@Vu5XAVbN/nli8HHc6d5OKHAZAOva7JKJEQvlzApHPAHgE6uFH9IQX7Z/yNKx3pxyKiIKDYB2zcgcFmiiQydxvVX@7cmq1mloZrq6qWm2LHvJ5VduqqR182NpSO/S@hfcfqmuPH2@IzN1xv9DHLfPxm9oiGLzDudo6H@3QK6VVcW8M1tro4pVidcXbWGlWn29uRMXj2hau9dPTv//X//7v/@1/FGv65X/hZYtfjn@OMxUKheJK68vKD9828H68c5JbOT1eGZ7kzjbAZX9nr@GDxjjvJ@ajhdFpZllmAesr25GadTZ7n9FFlYnl1/NHn0m6VNRyKyou66@RRI5iGbvcCqzvAe5RntIS3gQdmF7KZxDUredPsB1PvdMKYIBH8w1RknCBHaiUl7MVs3EPdzBxhvhUZVl74mGd9TLAnZbEkwLu4tKMlQ/7UdDHDvgl67zSvEzGp99w3NT8W/z5TXS2NbhWDz456kFJPfDUg2yWf8rrz@iru1IMcTtXstFyIJv1KCU5WoCZoYpCVvR4/cCxdqbIncmscMgeQDJuKjiz3ILz4tUfX5aRgGvRWWYJ4T6VbJHwIROKLH9Z6X@jbvlCOb5lU1dtWFFo6lUMV2adqMT9CxXIj8QQIKm5JwSpDKhKnPTxjWQ8Fc0X3dcZjibEgEHWg5e7PO7xgeailb62eU6tpRDmiM3n5Svmxg25DM1oI0XqTxDgAxVZTpb4JmFuOZcRK2@rldxMuYVtt08zn9g6TIKxsU2XQn9TFhOINbdNuJW@vteiDbnleEVlw/h4xaoqO237rTJWkd5FdxwO9XUFrh0D6ktc2zcZSehRBiRwxGd/ZXaE8UaB8RQ11S0SLGui2gM0XUZCX19Npw52C3JyZBGh@LNDY/vr1Nh2i3xLxLCD8AAjFZvydfywG2mvKyMm9pk/OkV0QL/DAdXGcm7G@3mI2jqF8aATI11gyGxynoxnasrycOSf9XxPLe8Njkb@pEHTFmk@41bBpRbCBROQwODTVc9rnkFYWqS7hCkSN4UthxC8oDvR4dGkb7PxnRN0qRkK2u0KBkGKnZiSwddUX03RMeHq7@gEG@UZ4R2fRmoRy5IXlkYaUta@NsPDbGboZEwN9tiJB042I6jGI9Pwgi50gYm2xwe/JMm78BGg687qW4D6KsL6M9SP2eks6PupyWnYzZiL/sUNJfMixjOHohRrpIyG8qScRLwDVqRH/pz2AiFzk3FnlFlynKVPkQ7ntmzPI@zkO7bFL/oqjAPQcQAzvhmi3vVDEZZTM1QSA6OgGmz5TxA6Xf@M8Jtc@ROw4qdl58d7Rff450/9kwfOp/7XT7@7jIkWyWaWzatlfZhtJJYeKzQzFr3Uq7FKi4yrwU/9dIZPfSV3WCwSECJF5/jn4snXIiH0adl1HxQ/LQtBUl0GTIo311cE@OIMmstpLIrLmSX3gWs63/mx7CqaW/kXfSgfXPklLMyikrfpaZ0z6hAovqf724VcOYmKT9dKj9bKj2gldBZc50fBBebbfHRxGlyTKhFhOUtTz6ffU9yQIsS368jfoI/X1E4JayJ3TyJ9SUmLUD3MuZ5MzFZUpiA8QfmJyuwuFVdc3DiPj8NHLPg9RSxn8rIvKDEdtLjPwfwZDXqox48g16ZvhwhHwspAbER4CzUPyCb4yiIOdc1wyfE9p4Lahu9WBkLdW1y2Zov@oJ/XyppbyG1Aicatme7T0tPS9BidGaKpEbqilancPVXe/PHJv/3P/d@Wx8uba8UPI/odL/@2vP50WR7pgd4emrfL5c3l58i2/m15UqQ1MD0@@bf/TeU3/0JwkDJ5Tn82HxtY65PlzXyVi3xd3lynh/LaGtX7f/71X6kNK7JiQyzWlaanGLENQ5Ftv8@8S@mqgVbKsjSXiBW@mAUYYmFIa3N6gWHU9drTEm/TLWuristAe74y9ih6imfDrDGbCslOhrGnIM1IClRRQV5AGhOKjrJsN4zZBpg3QVP9cr@wHtEK4BdtzhFXGZtu3I9gMrQiyyLqQEdqpPW8PGyWfszG5h2VrLEp2TAqJJZ2WtY@fbhB7PB2EIzDVtpKwgzXXsu/Ck4L4MNC0L6gNVU/6g5@HRUviSV75bWnxQ4294tsx10cMqT8cFL4nRRBHQyIFoZsdOqpEfXAoAcXXh5HCyKFfjc@kzLxJEnLHgYt2cNKxySmLHLHz5PjYTSnkKjSDv8lBR6RM3UgSCtW2qc@ldw/qKjsapxR8vGa1wU2b9k4VrvAyIs17JBlUyHDbcDuoGlPoTY640tIXApe1yVLwW@3m75OczJLWRMqzcssnQfdYTXbEffu8J2KExNNf1EzF0LJh9hByOdZ0AFWLxj7tESvZvkL1uNJDXCTos9aY1dxCVk7Oq9e1berHHXlhqqvpOor6lFoCUk9Mc9Y3tiUnU1kSxVblaOgiSO1uRVTbZEJ2jwq8A8wiKRbGh1cS9DN4RuQRLWkOdqqzO42j9fCxCNXgdzZk61FiVydWU4uP3omh9yghu6EegtSGQkIeMGtwEKZ3g/lBkTVhBkN@xnx5zeVbPx7aDDchn24ErXd1onzUZmW@peIfROO@S6lIhJov7K2DXZGZo8YdOxiKw5Bm8XGS9YFS3UqvNjijKY7KhwG2riEymZln@q4peLwsh0dvVYCRdCHbKm89vDR4/UnT58hytmSbu18MChUwCpgeO4TDNaoHVpk43u1ms1l5RNCUM9WCejzwOIADmZdV65r3D5fufeq5ZIGVsoyrCsOoyHF9XYlg0wgjoICZgRaozijrOP8WDlGw04@td2v9I/42/gHZIYz7mh9Ib3VD28Tz1SZnjgcqLJgZqc4zkN4UHF1ip03GHQO4G0igK2rsD1V9BoeIMbno8HF2bnNHQXt2uqIBgwRnP1SYwX1MhgnDsYsrKCL6g2HhnX7omrgHc@2AEa5mBKg8wlwGmbab6WvLU0xOnI0CcGzJm6s4gjRMh212Zm5sz9Q9b2dacSW7TB0DLdgW7aScseezOBABrF6reYeEXW1twu@SqplkpfyqswCroR8Zb4O7@OudAuBqC2qGFnNesPYuYksZebFxLVpUpT6EXjNgVku3U5Kc6/VtAIEMYJQ7ybFQsyLz3NskiU42Z2McQpezlYsG9E3YRSxgzldWdbVFqWciaMKLGUWAMS@TSkrDSlV0KP8WOfAy9LbCOYot6KxNaDNkOOVajA3J4eZYKvbSBxgI@q4oQXa39jb9tROnf7sftjxoChv1X5Cu@MQz4vxLWt8yxXV2DVdYHuLZZtb2Ez9hitKxCwl7TA2QRDCtyNREYPEa0C9satpL4P6ODW2TxKuALv6Wgk3u6N6kMDRC@@BLOnFe@yKg6/r8LeKbF7NSprYpYoeFrLFdfPAtmiylNQaQxJS3gHE2jSI2FFLwu1LCcOLBTpr3r5euxjGbuzO5@kUy8qCitT23SKRPc2zCylzE1usabZYq6Afb@IL5tsbeeM06Az0XbSYOW7hjXt/jDfyd2eO/P8XzFH/53DHQ80dDyuQPcIdsdtwvtHJYdgHczjmdMJzcLMdnoXYH@pYr2hEybMAsMADhrhDSonlEtq2QJwoZ37C6vR8BCOhtce4GPCHGv9IN/5RBTKXH3eC/1cbn/8HN/6xbvzjCuaaOT2vVTvL3fo/psWJSuikP8ztXqi7ks39oy1d1y1dr2A2ndPN/@ktzf8HtfSJbumTCjwmyIGDuK@/mZtFE6kdbjcaiblFIaOddjmIYz@fK12svdrVLC0eOt2L6LwKbV39YfyfavyfQhrxE8LQ4Switg2N1/KyPJXL8qJZ8i6HwiUraYm013hGt9qrJ6xkPaInKBHSvLE10gsVUsg9SUxOmwqJ/phI33jyuSvOItt1sEwcnFsLaFkRlt1kiIvmq4Nkrq3H88oO@0BW20cHr1f/i5Ch53/Wt9AIeXTtVdDtmpnEXoIdxV6ndGOs5gD2oV5zpFhFk5ORHevb3jG7LC2WauzYYmpenL9IkKM2nP/RWqoHfcOKyo0tI6JNQZc3qyqY5prlhXyhtkum@U3WLf5DXPpMc@mzijrQC4NFpPL1hp/mxWSdtvb48U1zgJQq4AcDsORR/htG1f8F)

[Interpreter](https://github.com/bangyen/esolangs/blob/master/register-based/dotlang.py).

Code: `•#407#`.

The code is placed below Nial, otherwise Nial breaks.

Answer (score 0):

## 417. [⫸fuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%E2%AB%B8fuck), 18170 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희吾有一數曰二百八十一書之うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+R _*=x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +R"12"+8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ?
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ?
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.   ; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 













































































































































+ f 
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{:before{content:"345"}:after{color:#fff
}}</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5":ngiogrlstd[*u""]!!48 在ｕ2\0C0+---42ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri:s9   Ford: EniariFFFF""bodyck^ x  \;npp ay 23   
 ; ;:
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({0da0d6db-f27d-4093-92e3-c2991af8d7ab}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rc@NKdiD4sePC8yNSoKpIisSTb1KkpFKpbul2vVqluvf6kiwWCIIkSiDAAkCJLIkV9/bM9rrHPTN2T7en3X7cdns92972xHgnZsbtGXsmwt6PE4755B9Qfmxs2A73P@g9JxMAQYmU6rbtDcdCIpCPkyczT548eU5mItHVvOFPfpLAizxxrNnAcnziG55Peq55argiuTMju5rpFdQcxyHUnjuYjAzb96pcgiiEWJo9mGgDg/RNyzfcLPEMg3QNyzmDeJWQ7Yk98YxeA3w5QmzjjBzautkDDMR3TgzbfG24EJcn5K5hXYwufKI7o5Fm9zwydk3bp7EFQp5o4OlP9BOidT3f1XTfdGyIKi5lUVrylQl56LieAZgc3fA8B3FVlkAUmbyvQX5jy5hewqwo5CPTcHuElmLsGqwsiko@PL5373JojnxZcGxyD0t4KSpP9ia@c@hfxl8gewPD1ogqVkT1cmQR6OQbVlkuy5ejStBUhm/ql/Mpk71@37QN8hDqejmyQnTPEzzdNcc@B01J7pkuNLMWNCfRNRuaDRt1ixijsT8jAmMEzbKiRvaI5pGJN9EsCmdPRl3DDQE9X3N90x6QM9MfEn9oelE6Cu2NNd0QeoZljkzf6BHLhEROP8ACqO0eOTFmZ44LbR/gdGxrBgkN3eybmCQsByDEK@UPDYZnpM2AcWwfuIRoxINiWEaILc0lAP6u0Z0MiDPxxxOfQNl6pqd1LUDanZGe0dcmlp8lXYiDJqHhZ0PDDrga0ImA4thhpXo5oUUzFsyv9XpEBoaGcpwYxASq0WJVSS4H4cRxgWoAFZYoQEYZnNXRmEILQ5v1nSopyDLEH0QhWFrN8pygMMtFw0gbOi1tM8T7xHUGrjYCavQMStMPD58QT3dc8MEPYVnHug6Nrvlke5skDx7dTZJG1Cyi2@WiJqqTc2iCRBhJTjVrAhwSbwkH2seNUnPYZMmNZJUkgSyqTPJ5kof@WyZqAYikyBVwgCBQcwr8ikQtk7wC/a1AcgCcU6FzFyEGOgTJy4VkFjPvu9rAtAyGeoCoS9h3II0KdzlPctAtcsUcgx44Vp@B6rQUJZIrk2KJlAqkBPcKqahQDMwzDz2mAL8i/ABjBcoIiNQclFhWGbJFpwAmRkbcJ31tZFqzIAeahU4KCikBVqiMAtjVMmCBZy6Hvxz8yoht@Yrj9ofQFEPtFNALlnmCssyIxBm2rwQPaWtLonITBTPL3hti9kBXoGihTEqQfREokociANnVMmRfkFlFvKFhWUGyoYfJaGlLMvyg5CWgRRmaRgaaykjUEvzAD6JTBRmpgkBUQcapIJdUFdw5zALgsK2K0M7FPMtmqHknkBHLR@3RBgC5D2gUpDjKQwWJBBig1QiQGnggD1ySQy4p5AiUH8pSKhLggLJCynlSLhGgZ0Um0D4KlAtZSAFRrEB5FEQGfKAAIyhQJgWorQBSJVcgXIzYSg7jIW0O0gJplDykyYMbGk4p4g/SAXcokKUCeapqZcGhUDa1APUt5CjrqkVo3RLEAd1UKKsKLIX8qpYhHtOWgYZl5OxSMssIoSEdoFWwLwAvAjEKUB6KF2DBrZYC5tWs8VDrouBnKbt9TFrEPlJEMkJSGasHzzxSE4oiAxrsDVB8FTggR7sSPPNR9pYCSJqI3uiZVHpbOIIoEYVKWcqQL7WxvyCbUqQlGs/8YRSmsjAHpKoJktEYaPosioRemI0iF6HFHIaqVBAvEMl5DPVA7DoTz1ogiRx5lWZlnJrWIqxMw3qG1uub3vDNoqx5mknX0HzbPFnkUihkY0TVYhFFjFgKKuXisL4pwFg2GKJrURe1hDBjJ2qgpSIrCi1e1@hP7IEhVMqx8tEYf@L6MOos8qywYNccDGAEX@BRsrSadBRdBBdoCa1cDgb3MBCpi3m6Joztt4k@BN0kiqww/JXKAkdORRwzrYtDvgC6GgwRFRzU@uaUdG/rdEhZFDBH6aQPzXEIXF0LHGtcmsm0XIzxBqXc67IciWe82uJLx7RTSZJMc3MOBiKmf8aHcRjtPsIhDAdlZF0YdB2qUizEZ8oOh800EG1ZA4Ah2UJNqWvoGg7POFgZdLAN8Zi@SCATUCIN5xSVWzpiLmXj0VG166IuCypQz3BdgrCgAHtZOv56k65nvJqgkrUoVx8GdAPG/b5mWlEB6Dii@VQ7gGfSg/xmy8Xuu86IDjYjHF8txxmv0WVgND9DRPedM2NR9MVgr43HFqhUEG4wjQ4Kc6ZRrZyq8PFcWYEgEaaDBgeENCtQRUzX0Cntg6pD6hwoLctFrBK1cTuHWO7EdK0cdBbQQzxMY08sqwpKkKGTXEPqGacShjB9bFkPwzKEGhroWQGKrgZqN5acliLCdFsVqe53HLas54yWq8bG18Oo6kMTtSbrTJtB6/VhaDWm2giMA4IaOPRcMgKOYS2ILQFWBFbrkPQcO@lHWM5c0HCh0lFNqBaNNPHNkQE2kgNJsMXztNA4utOSdWfAypRaeZEaRawklwglcpcJxQLysQDWWUAX7E10pBrmbdqUg0Bd8tAAcEFUsjDOd0mrpcHPBWVvHNiBIjoQ8CkWLWZOeKy3B2q5TjGiAmvYHlgonkhMtNKA8wdOH5jtzIS6g8CCpAvcOiUCkiAKmoq6yFGSIwONTixiEn08JhAOgxKw5z25DPqp89IkryHSGoJ9oU9cd0amY2gJcwRQvu70@8C9r43xEFCQUY/oMx26JzQy5R5vaGtjrudQMaOPlyu78G0aAGOj3bL/5GfJwADig07bR6sRGX9RjfGYVoQSRLOZvmtrQC@siD6eUeJwiUWKvuOIGN5zDI@yjOOeRAIAM/OMAe0g0Nv6C5E0Qv0deNWmdkcP5E/QyRA/ZsitrAxmFfDC@4YNHUgH3oSuD42ILbtH@mCQxxRZNEU0XTfGfsAtDhVqph0zCR7fQ5OAhgoBMtEbcpu7ZPsS7wBoxD8xjRZNJCz6OLBUNJS4gdUvUPUjskqZfLFmV7IHiNNLufMvEGapBC/4NWUY046B9hEVFRMfBQrKSFMfokT0UeZQrRv6nDu5Wn0Ii2fvjojQj/LG0iggfDhRioKwHOtxCPCzriISxxbiaiwFIOhSwA2oNW@0ArMTFdLqxUNFSRNBNN6EdOTYzgqsQMwIL4Isx9C2oMz4FGWHZkXMSLuLt9RGKLYXE1E4nMFIOh47LvQMJnpmdLKBNlmMuwIbPRWNGGmR3FkeYGHgSOKw7@NYCAnGlga8gF0MeyrYVxrICxBlzIYGyeewHGMFpr2e4grKd0YHAMZMMKLatoEmmubOGBKoHgzSkNGMmK4LwvAUhwo2EoVDikj5FEYGrddD@YrkoP3@cuYicvT@pGtOLxvqOgaKLz3uVHNJH210F1QP6ESpZN9Lpms0nKaMRfGSM/YlmpTdeQCkQCI0eaoPZj8MFfdA0Dyd2XqKX@pifJbwE79f5tPgwIRMUyMfgMFwuXRoRCDTjE6gX1NfjQxgEBcEuAsYRkuCEZKIEZoL2gZ0QrA1K5VeVyMXID1cIkz3mUESGiaKmI/yMuxelFdACCxLvL4iy8JzdeoQYmMb1gDBac3pILFEwHekBE3IQ4AkBSMsBlCdj8VR7YYFTmw6sUdSTCFJk/NIBYYBIEULY4IKYuqm3wmUltu3Q/Vlo14HZgOdCsRmLx23a8NJTxEkNQCLVCcJMhF956mPfSOVhvoi8JyVBpQn4NR6g5z7Qxd6HPXPOQACsnI2cnJI2KCdH5knk97lhrYxEIF47HWgOpm6z9c4UAFYb6hfR9XkElXB9k0iVZF5MT1FfYV5aSg2KB@AuYaHSnA9KEqshVNYgoBXV5KIJQ3CFgy9P9OtQCVgLujsTBp1ofgnwVxXJIiygU4QdtorPZUhwe7A8JAne8f360FfZJFS17SrSwGWo2sWDd5EcD5M@@DwztHe0c92VuCwzG71coBk5stFHGonU2FgT6S8qFY34zgWiO92rseNCZdheC6IJoIzjalKMx0Gl2lIzsdHX75MEtCEkBw0B3Dj75JKw2BA6eK6mje8NAiTQSYDWUZJQlgiHJIQZ@TAomO8FpbnyeT1a2y8y4UaB@FYMmuiMQRhoHRoh@lEjLykgIVR3T4bEWla0EVNGxcyFq44ZFie91F3vlwYqlDHWOb9x/cOjuoUbTC7JlAQyfNBl9Lcngg8b03AEF8FA@IPXDrJiIuCo1ZNy7qSwLq@ROBF25I1@AEBWjyiQwRrFFbNG0LZ9y/XjYYKesQB1E8xXNYr4/qQ/kULGisHDnE6Gr6rRlEasRisoqCVI1YUuzxs6YWCUcpX4sOWvsizF0dK1w1gHAj1RheiTjwBQ8SFFhmo1UHxnz64UnCPKpFgCghhyTyLiDQvz@LQehFMkvSkfbDTHMsQP6ISjyd8WpKS4dKBqHvUBI3BH0xNPyWn2VNJAyzkvrd3qN4NgYOJazqfQY0GtMhxZHL7uBaoe8AjtmM5A4dsQRqmHYYZgtq0tpp7A8e@0kIaBmJVE7icCPIXp2@0MYw15mtqPtJUcaOVLUxqtncGUlop5pBIlEIUlUThxZfaqQbkWtT76eEnBzCIKAVZjtwyvYAEsTSUXOjSY6E0gAiQkRiUZ2UFo/XHK709jBBiC4BY6UDQRQn3FtErA6nEFKWV8CuL9IFzheIvndkl1oIQxlrgiJHs8NGTB4ePDh7ufdzy1UJhyZ@XK0UgHOTXBV1IHDK6YW/dYl0Tq4XoEtA3XOxeIAUmYKCEC0oTzwXBLSKIyAqwhmvYym3qA2doJ7305cqcYazw0tYZCz3EzsdAg4RgaPcsNEZctrKN4znyz9D3x15VkqCXDyddEYxW6aXuWNpAoulgYLAsSUHT5fAxzm54q1JAYbyZwVKwKS5QHWZ0HlGzRg4YL3R9HEUDSTH0dO7KMgdDsIVxEd1w02LEwbQ2Ug8sBLCVpahuVABTH9A2eIbtxDPWfk9Ry4yvFVnNS3wIttT9AXajb4DplILRCkiRvuQlrdut22QGUhoxXUaSIOIWneTwCI4FFgFFks6dop0fEodKC5w1RVlBafRqgnO6IKWkgpwvKcWCBGYZmGmgswo48yaMNF8fCr4jAD7B6dN5gxgX9j1ds/viVuAICwt63y2oaq75vNWy26Cgt27TsuHSdHPWbirtdI1cTbIVwKdrwL1L1UPeDQOAd6kTWJM@yRp51tOuirOeRntXj0j@aByMOcKYPNwDReq1A/K6Z8T7HiaQ4pHS1hKshMBvpBUTQhYm5fCGlJKgQ8FIC6wnYbkEUHpRPQTOAbkVS0AWsxmRwjTzhyA/ciS1T13pqxouBucCqbFcFJwaFsczEHkUCIW2kMMChRE0wzHDgEVJggmEGg/GJ1kR6ETCsQsifQzNxCa09mEgAHPOw6lIH4dgXLOZsLlh7JKBFyc894RPiCa8vk65CKEB8dsf/qgf4InUNpHc0ZDjgAqXNLsgoUieoQiAsXxGfDrT0DPQjMf9Ec9sEw0RkaOxAgxdyc2O6LsbhIe83v7w995@9qtvv/HZ28@@/fazX3z7@e@8/fzfbQhv0MZsbGdaLUHMNtuET14p/K0D9dbenVt3yrSEoE9C4c9wniJe8iBTyHM4hCHtPqhQza1bZ@dkY2MDcGxs7ABZNnZ2SIbswF2A@wYMYjsQm4X7DmlC7AZpk3mbA3PSIyum3kQ6mS0amj7sgOjSjVQuLcL4c34xvSDDYXMqQqc74fUtvj2nSz1UMOPyByv0PlLwKd2vgmX/AMZS5lsUfl3WTanVlFvt1nmq1cukW3Mpq7TB5O2YePNSarqpiKIAYdjRU5J4Xp5LUdmmFBKARH3oLkpGV8/Y9hk0bBn33TOnMCyA3IJWjU@Q035OV1pwnvMTYzycuXGAaPIIlEWcCF7sysDNKyiM4p39NUsf10uWDNZQfWNwoKPhHBQO@@MZE1IcK2lLWtoUFA4fp0J/5Pia9KEIur8Yk/rJjaQkCCDQaQzDRKv90PR00PM123AmXnzCbOU8HuYOocfDCcjS/aE55gx96AC77wJOEi1ZIJFx9UVgazhhsp4uwg/7GPZfnO@HoZFumDGh8WlXolMKCs36VLPMXjSxXCiOX4lRbjWahsiYkTmwHdcQgBCQgqO7g@jmM64RLq0e0mmbK4IriKXyGIWgafhZcs9yNEpRxwZeiHEjLkws0oNxCUmOjB5n2UTowzgvshZwjZ60xdGFRscdguyC2uD6iRq10SiIkBxv3BP9KSTlUjhaxCOZaQIa0xnpqapa1Av9ahiHvADEHkLToEllg30WRgkKRKaDpj1gcxqhgfno8d0DZvjTkQLHBpwE6oyc3gSUokDpPzLsQZYcABeZtjMCuWaH6V@fWEeO4zMTFTzrphWYxWeOJpZGJywuzylcm053uo5F5zGuS7qAn7ieZmlsBiWM3fvwISiqz46f1sVqDEjSTkfX5o2TaKuzZfQ8jC@b0SXDcG3DY4zJbxZ4HHPC7Y0oXIKIMkaMcAMjKG6BSUu9UWAAeK7Ic4Rdq/tHcAqFYwrLIqNzRaXhp36/vxSco8EnAsoSaxGcp8FsU@OSbeJ2F0AFBoQ7HJdg4oiKFCba6LgWrkTh2N4KYNZFRJlGaHTbo4Dz6EuxFRq72PeIqkggwaLV86FhhathR8bIwRUfGCUtXFoAPRu1SrYz0YCxYowT@1RM43IRDAkaJLys9UAXGwsMmkts0G7TNW0JV224TYkE07U12nHABGbLbB4ToQ6YqXQmYLvBlmfRDHCZBSKxieTNDqDYbtTCnWLrwDCnZDICo1hp2SAFrSZdkb5S1Wh/gUfnhzmapMZ5EmjAU1UWWtPSQfsiKXmUDH3Ct1rTW7L6MSgmuAdw87Y0MGp0c84aetXCmCQV2MFYzlEoNteqD0G6kMx0mZTQPhO771g9gS3sAK8RZhJgAwWr69HexGALqmG64bZEui@UJUWpGtvReAXvpSZtXAWI7YGMEKH6QC5OsqcXpHmSJaeiN7ZMH1Qk1CeGwRYf@/JuSbq4pLmuNvO4YHNGnewdvf9hU24zDNxIw8WaMmvFabjpFkwo15ngNmlw4RYT3/TpqE@X0E2sLyg5kIDO60PxAQfLoEaijIIaUc3HuFjUpW@AcZUyqLo0G2WJkZ6LfUvzfcNmPMdWzNaTmy1tBNnUafY7wTx5lch0McHsQykhDopYI0@P7x4cHYmo0KWSB7joUIXuCKojKCPrKh1SMl75KrnVS5JbmCaNliYHXQ1s506QHpi6Bkw/MXBpBcXOwHBTEJjG9QIdgukSDU3ItLGAQLhRSPcpjSJkKbB8dxiy6sryP7NPbOcsavEqcHyGUhLInbpdRS0zLU5s85XowfBCFU0ACYwbGCXqmykqyTaVdLATbISrnaBUUwURatBsEjBg@E0A5km7XWPL1gALcRCG1OV52hR0b3ZdCZu@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@ruubAaRc0LqKIbEt19c0uaudTHqOMD4ZRHpqcQXsovZ0FkkAdSBYweygc3X1WQXZFubwuQ5sMbRJZ/RxE1d49sQbC11qe/eYj3aE0TU5uBa7rwMxg3fTIsd6qpkWvb0jJwbYgVGCBXwJN0kKMaKZl8hsad0Z6iDDL85l0WI4SJy6nsnIuTWroePx@vRob9L0lcrq1FNRZ/RYNTMgsY2YgeFFKxxszbyhVWG4MkeaJai9mHOtMF@1ln4FNFqGo2nwrQH66sC1TI4Dkj6xNHfhuobFr8z8XplDDoaLJ6bugBowJkpJVNRwyIgNFFRUhru4Fhng/ld6i63Um6vIF77/IESu1V3f0X3c3biGl95BkLFdhbh3M8YcorOOQrpzhr@1asMQTFJ2Xz2SvV5ZqncQSoKlWxqM32uHgaWpQJxqvIFBz0zPoLfVhD1ZWVBft1aGL7N@OMkXn7S7iZ0903I88pTeryPQwAUqsPtqRo7T0tRsgU54x93XyJ5wOX7RoJo1cKxieSBpcFvb6hO3j/I@eL6rZIskk6LcIJlCtcexleC5Vp6fSO7JTQ1E37BzcStmzHnN0LpKPAUrHOtrBwYBvmqwumb35DJNKUpsInBNxrgB5Uybhc@fYshYR9pwyBjPqBoNWh0mqJTB4btMtf5pcstfn1vv3YTSFbSlmyoRa9wTy4BBit6vNClRZeULplBk@d1FVN@aGBNjpYHxuPvSwFfKrzEu3r1QclCNzWBeHpcC8F2KCOp1YBG@U6lxfEbftcJEw6W/m1WYZaE2Bq17jCbzE3A8QcfVFAN7Ml5q1SWrzD66nmTDcdilnd5S6TDmi8qh8g0a0pJe7hn0d62lxCw73MtUL8iyHCgusfWVJc91FlQuSvvSZPeljGnIIucFLK6puTHn6jwoWeK75daKIHWdQU@BKxXJNm3Dn@H9HaVp13GsL9JSIFTxDVcHrFSB7gq9rsWuqDvB@w5kMWXh4URHt79usoKNNoFNCfRBY/m6Ro8vAL1Tawq4xDnC5adl7@o8cDrS0kbdnkZS3TMnvUL1XMoCX8XEiSC2SdRar0gGUyCKWBZL13Y5pp46XcPS2GNazF@HryLmrsW3LDGCdVlcx2Wrt4u19sQliTSeAaXMHpgmQ2NkUO81qr3Ww9MegsdaoKmDv3XRU8PQpemBoa8DGJsgFGy8Ly0XxzQl37HBqPJxPxoaJxbueAxC1xPxoeaazoO9R@8v7T242vJVcjjSBgY7u@Q6qbmYtMBtN8y0WzhXT19UyR3srjokW2S@nkOgg50YMy98rkT4cKZDM09GN0@5XRIEOs6DvkPPX7fz8upwaw@doT00hmy7c@Rb11eAPX121sx1RYdSD4a4A2s8XtqZHaen5UCqd6AnikkmNB2nv7JMB/jmJr5w9IXwstfEg8eNE3iaz0QJOtZ2oqExgTHKc3xnbAjUtw7Uwskedl8nT8M17p92FulaWx8oEj5/Wvw32pkDzfHHY/rojK2JR280qUBfuL1Jh@qzTSl0L5/jDsTXzqgrBoFisGOFLoOvljhd09eH@MYz42xj4HT1oXlToYNTFqRw2od538mORcqYRLiLwaJlAnndmYj8Uo/HP8XH4bpGD2aQ2EAXOa7RXVbN0tF3ioWxdqJ7bEYUXaSKk8Kx3sjePK7Sd7erryamv0Aa28UUTfGypQl0rCt7sPlirZZFt/YvxHCwKWMtl1KFHZVzwZBB@VHWZbu8ry3WxXI5dlspM3RHP@mH01prKRls6KGTf2ZsWhbCl1hnaSfSSmvCHk4G3lVZyGbje6CJ4W397ATdXRubkYbhSLODxzoKqpaEr93BswOq1cS4dsmkcO2aCYVTLEFzTHh04AGtMlk7VWaZY4/didBfu9IWbFACk/vyciCjzWy1zRw0TM/osxUOdN2kb44cFxTzAWgbgo4L5ThBjnKaqRRMJtnOAOS1YJEFcAi7zj5cuYFodfNHw6Hw8SNjoOHW3gemj/suV3AF7R@rNh7diPsrE80zvzKBmq1jNjxJgK0yuvFtp@hbge@hNjD1@0sNERUyIHCwaZM9ltgfg662xdnQ9HDDUuS4Zv4JWY4xMXJdB8yDFZCXp@WjQxQWHYi9mLcSetXUuTOe4ftLM@q6btbc9OlkavBcZyGu2x52bSHOJqPxxAseq8tAt0TFJ5tHTJx5ZyYgF16B1CRDzfJXT0jHZlZBwQrGu4VzdZZV8olpOQPySVkmoI@BfoV69wrGuQMj7xPcb@PaKziR5v2Oq5o4nyG4rGKvoG0N3GZvm/71kza@j3tvwidWhg0KzhnoAw/wLu5@UQzC8WqKPLhZjV@8LHvD0A2c99SZuLqBzugEjLjGH@Rq7Idbik08MwBP8DiL22O6Y0H3Aoe1ssvojj3xBXdiXzsqFK8dFap4ClKMDUjqKwcPn6Xj3EA3Xt@kYIbnZC1ca/cDXGIy0wYda70cXYYOzYS77PyeI7r/94Y0e3jIkE7F9V1nlSnzZAYDyDvbQiD8J6O7ho6rgjfm/ch56NgOjEZjEJSjI4O9hb60j2N1Qkz2AN@zBvr0bszmKUW7ZhBi2oY2NrrQvtbC9S5jEUN8V/O1NUMRnQKkpl3kupFXTKtruC/p3F7Mvc5aXS7QfWNKzYb1DMP6oODrOtN2cdptqY8sLcx4Y8ex2Z1KWxkeysPrpQoMBfT27uvgIu6uXzL5V5pey1V9fMo2gRg9dkzCurq6Rtex2P2aLUe2yZb8Ndc0POkBvnVPw4p5IoD25V0rQ0rXypCF1QOa7Knm0TX41VbEAqUy/QI7fIaaqzu44BU4rtl8E3tV/gYxHW3YZ/sCukD4KUgsTZ8Eh1jeVCxr1B3R21qDIdaaRwZk08OdgU9ntq9NrzYmm/QJXq6PbdiKXkkPxRV26iJJPQFrJH3zsBU3BC9R1RzTG5XUa1fF6V4cwTYN/bWGE2IOpddiCnopHuosPaLONVPSsW5EJ4sljb57vbInLe9MA4XGMgR/6II5L/nXzWKHB3@sWPaYjAxcS15ebFmrujrekFbWWb1sHglX1xCCM@hAlkTn0TH9UNhbq3kievh/fOcDCQbhTjEfHoYBouvmhXoo/MS1g8e7cOATx/P75vQxlBs3@a8TJ1itAiSBB@sZ6NpaVwloPXtisYmFQWxb1ahHzTGBHh0sCBYV174hGPapQI8mm16tkcPe35L28FRZ3@gJwZv5uKAgPAhf5YrAgueKddK4bMS9nIrECDst5oPdnauIexZKBtC3HF8Ye/Qpjb0nhw8eH4tjT1k5Pu0N8eWHK3rc0qv@almOzTa91NzYsibbbdYzPV@681QR9h8cigiwht5s7UKABy7ALT3WTmmGp4tK2lorCGMNf7WCeP/44YPM4s1Hktofus7ISMej958@zeKLJB88XRkdT30Pekffma5NfnigKOkV7Bu8q7pOeq7IaR2mYwOsUWDG@@ykkBuVK90ZG73j2dj4EAZPlODeO2ZfXFvJR9qpOcBeSCprCUU7KqmIxXw6tvEajG3DjZ7r2vPEHKO01OlDYo@1u05Qc8hJbm619nDdwv5lLYbIwYaDL5ZIka9ya/x8W0nz/q4FUxRlHZ2fan1oV1JY21jLAKuWgS3n9B1WjI3AeBGiIMEHrhLMG7eJl4QRiG4JbzjzHgSCs7t2t8t1CKLg4soOf2bYM80W6DLVdepFFVLj3rVrQT4x3mGtKdrIc4qHaK9cvot2zJOUTp3pGzI@dmNJ9vfvHN6U4Cig5fVQ7z96Rp5oHh6LcT1gvMTGO5R4oRm9FHDeCs9kWzeBc9hzAZV6Lb7BeHV/rpKnmttz7Nn05vU1@mIpDu302NIIF/ookGGZU3PVWKWzea0nq3cT3ZQ3e0fDmS3pwfHjUgJEb7/2i4oiy/QwHHwqMvPe0DJhBycpdGkzPGEtHnV8GIkGHfUWEQLSK63RB8YUd52w2eBVRv3K8a14zdhXSq8fTq6LK18Tl78mvytxGEhyoqxcg7BwTRwpiFH0A8c6GzrivuYa3soV/xUFuq4ilWsqUolJ5@AUb7pmGLjXq/j4ZkLwWMmtx4bv5sdDp2vmr9mvsvz279olD19z6Y6WgRO82sH8qzM@mxgrqfZQe706goqck5VRIA2N4YS@@nA1enkRtAvKr2EPTHb0H7nj@AfUd42FFr0UvXq/gTm@OxmvLzEISfxmwmW5vgT4ERjPzplH7uArcAt9fcUkAO6HWx2@Trkl0QwhnoB5/3gvZLPHTyU1luOiFB8/WQrGl0T9x09jYa4xna6zfoXpOmNyZcwi10fH@aVstxvPT1cQa/17RaB3gGCOnmsVIib1Pnh6VTagHTf0R1YY84FmL6ZOlxqs5/j0jcKVkU9mU7ptcmVLD9mutVVxrn7TljEYmU0T8vakTgeP6el01nHlsfExXYQAfYj4TD9hSIPTsIxpfhiWkCZZ21Gdk4UWtFTcp@OhaU9XRo3WpaG7RlMvvdXdYI88tZwzEhrD68WDuhq5dmqsouzalxKFSu56dSx3Sbda1y7s8xrBY12T3FmnsV2SGbjp4TppgumPdOle6PlQTd8I/8HTEPxm2H3LwYn8njkZ3QxM0WYyNwO614i/ywjNm8HwaxQnQ8e1bwYN2alavWO8YyE23hlyNNOddyhDt9@/GejAc24GejixfBONl9Wgj5yJhScFrIo7cAcrwxvbjVZLrIrrIvGgb2/optfHg9wfORMPjCEzEp5RQuGl6S8FhjwTD8Nzxw1btJ30JbwfOOTLeML4ClK8fsc2@uDeOrjllZsJrvXTN38XznVvgY5nuRs7@WtzQD3v0ulsc3Qt7OIouEPXsZkvvW54XBwLtyKn@5pl3ijQwp0P6g17IHBAY/HkNHez1AIF4d76NvtwNl3Yncu1t9jhEqvi9lUgykDX0@EncnArupKLzf6xPWZrdvEuRv@vHIw03UvH94PFTrUJ15O9dfpAfEJheVh/@ujO3vFHTx6sjP2yNuqulvfh1yTUu2zbaD@2d/iKehvNutKvb0hP8S54Qw1UKzrhKuBpF5cW6D/ae/Bk9cg@BPsWWhWPy4zNUi8G5lTP9bRRJb@6HR@GL5XeBXGF7nUDyf2Z4QiTNWRjituq2cS1L35dPpgPodkBEaB3xL@H4WWDo@DYgSrsGAtPDD9akkrZIJ7Sy9@Ji5/JgafGpzbx1ORNev4GwF5ckI3gzAuI4MNTNIJTPvBwVdOeGHhMB/t6lF/fhGzqdaVQITv4YbYqUWSaJ362ssLOsAwza5LN8@AEi2pVmZONOuGrPAnOEImOpGfHqgNiPBAaKkWEE4Vs@hCzGZ5/Qeh3gsgFofP6go7n7oJPlOInAdWCE0KgTJvnTw6fHDw93jt@9rQpt@fBCSJhLWwbcgvPKbqV6/FQ@YBuNhmzjyzQk2ssyI5@HAbXA7ywXgS/i7ZctfpS1RaV4ncwzea5bUsSPURFEuZQPoFnudFYVHYhiOEOa0wbKDg/p8rOM6HHskAbMdQ8zRMarUrkVRmPNc@DagXxlz8jSGPxG5RV/AolZhyciw88PXCcXpCjZ5CbrzDHe3uHD54dHZCwgAuuOTN7/rBeKbDPJgSHNPJ4pIpFTxtKBkmS0Fb1evJeEgiTFJOkSo@9oZ8swAMdkxE/4IE5Qeotktqk@IGCyahRpP/xqTRPiviiVBpgk2GhkpAt8DxlFDzS8hiYhNw9Ovzw4Ihg@Q/u0mAkEaIgx3jmxh//oMc@@hOehBd@f9MdBfYptJbnmL0qHoSjGySRV9TgNK0ewVMg2VkxxJjSD@hQzqOTd7Evcqbp6WRc/PSe8Eibxak72HJUAsRTso/z0NNsoq8CRR834zh62ibw@xk9ufXSoaZpelYh@9ooO244Qk1ZL/zACC7ygz1NR0zTM/EsHWyHvjNxL3USPMCCnuErkj38NCl@AFWj36@Cwk5snx27GBzFlgAOFSNZlSWbtLDsa1d8DDC5vQGdpGsMTJt4tglKl18lL4GDcSG9ys5aEoRG8kqSEHWVugQ0k2OAzMAf4VckiDA@wPMzW6709hf@hTSoEXD74P564J7Kd8D384GvD@5vMPdzCRlUSl75yFFUlniB8JDjoAasIFzf/MlP8GvFfGpTUU467mkmWZBrcFNqBVIgtzZbgrDZlOu7mxoQ0n81bUF3lrbyp8bdYb93OJBaPA8aVl6Sts7Pz5P3tp6YzwukKPRMtfhqOpvnirlX03lOKb86GSvFpvhq2ubL9exJu9VskydPPn7TeZPmp6ezVzDupIDB9h/zSp5PVCvkfKeYS5xU8AOHUMMT8hqukz7Bf@p@3Yu5NXR3@8C3SZ4kWi38tDBf4kHsJdvwTyXFC7iYzGg2xIa4037zJt3UNH8KqoRpjr1eD37OkKRUNf2UQFe7DZ2IJZBIiz4pEeEqjKZ9Mt0zBoPJgTYzJ/f8XbEklkU1Jpi2H37yUXDVPnr2jJBn5Nmz10drxFg7k0kJQpO6p2HgA9AmslNS7WiFBH6i8I9/tDHPnj/pbP/xZyPJ2MDHY3x8ff4Q3U@Vwq2NjVt37uTzWVVVmfvJJ09@dm9vL383W3jSLOzkBXlj@4/@cGNDVbdVaaPteUo72Tw5@ZhX5Twv/vH3k50nT77ieY3c//Xpm4aCtxLcTkmJVPDKEQWceC/DTyGFAnnXK/E6ocCVmNG/TiIMP98gSmOn9D@/9fhVwk80VOkjF55@4lWiWE4wJzjAlwt9p4lGYhvBivPETKrX6@As/c9/D@kbHwAejJltw61RCHEVZ4mGUKdJLhKNIjgUVYV8/59PP42VEOQZiJI67ZHhtQsCsdnk8yWV32nDtUWvbQ6PIBNkSQrhbH/oGw5RyreV2@gxwQMPGx44I9ZK4EdaH@8S8flRBsaEjPhhY0O6uy3AJY4lRVFbinIbxK9wa6teF2Bcod02lyvcxuNh03Q0HDi@Q4zbHy1diY/@Xq6VaGof/X1eR2Tf1A3XyXKJ4sbui7uNBtQ318htNTL0CjoZ7W@lMu84uyBrjocT13Twa6@1B/jdogYvl1U@m83uHnUgCZlOkYTCdCp2EAVhH41PsEvsEBaC3TkIZLwIVwMlQZtE4SxV6F3AkRfJJvSR9ov1cIkDvP7kP/7Jd/7kW/TvO/T3X/H8Nrtn9qUtADqF7tKAa7da1RsNvuHy5y30N4DH5Gq5WpY681Zqq9loH4Fa@/5FspBLkqfWLNvBbkNa6VaTpm/QbBtB9uhvJBbBDRbSiIcFEQyYBsAzoBRJhPWM1SuiGiGX4LhEuBVOaJ422gLOqNaFplIstAWWqrkLjcOrpQrfaSeEzRlIIrXdUAvqY7LbYBcZbnrEwdLk1GJYkaC8jUXdFjELXyMelGiEyRoLmC8KF5SpwiWaTalt0LGiERZ0d6O6Ua4Wq6rUaay/aosUeFFQwzCeeInTRHTVSMCHIT0TEWfGwp7HWyJqFhIyMFlKewMctBUIjek0@F9z0ebKFRW@FrjUDk9qwB9qTlAHHV5WoLftdiLlfQeuDfij/3BFXrxv0JAgmIJcvTZIVdlSc1LhVvFAxaH38uUKzUaGSkah3ciIKCEF8RIMB2MJ0bvd7mu9C5qJpnU1XVN8baJNtZnmdyfdadfXJzp@xJs8QfWuE5DBzTkFp@yEVBGFRK6gbCZuY91yagW/hw22Sbmcq6i5kpIrFXMlWS0XcuVKrpTPlUqAMFdSc5VKXlVzxVKuWM4Vi7liBb85DjBFgMkhhlIhV8lxiTfNDXLE5NuUZMKrlbnxeiZSiYYXdTj4EwRnmgDFCWz1LJf4B7gaiqqQLRgcZbiBRkidRKV/UMN9zZx4WY4kQNk7b7/Zar7ZIvHWEoIyw0Ps7LYzwnzeBHetFvxvNyJnjV7MBVVtzzOZ7ecN0IGeN5oZQPk8QCkKhCIVOw3S3qZRUW5BdkH8dhvUKCGz3dyuO/v0J9KuKLQB5fZSMXd3KV/tQsrGJnT5dCazKQgbTcDTDEYjAEbuC@oDmNop0FXOz3/KH0nmnWTR2d3eBrEy35435s3t@Xx7G/636X0ePCF0vn3lnz4W1xqYRXwbRVKrKTVaUisQS23wi1IDQ0SpBY4GPAGumVPLbRwIUdER2/84/8Xs4h6FYJHbIpSaS2yRrQQeX5ZLbHGJF28//z/w13r7@Q9RaSXwZ1S5xDkhXELaqhAaRh8V0Nwe2uQhu2xw4y/0YggGNB5ioM1uNprCkvRCJFWB2sMppVxMizjSd5x@B9@CFskLAAWwg4EB/SUUs4RXy0W@k1FmKkls88USlaw/c@VKJpP/5IVaKSWZuY2v8b7wPO9hrJSLcgJwTZUVQblosNOq2ecEfmbV9U9@Zt3FJS4qBGmUIowuXALYKCFJYCZyicb2CPeC4ndxBPzA4Wn9Y@HZnrDvjMaaT@1xnKwDraB@eFCvVBpoJxmbT2jX2bq7BXcF/g82oBKk1QfQVr@uj0AHb/VzBbWFZun7GpjnINOE7iv8e/Aa/8ixjn9Hr/CPHL/GvyMf/8jDLv4dv8K/vS7@HY/w784r/Hv4Gv@eDfCv9aVcTqnxm@eUPBmlosw3pzwlUw2Gs0brS747qxqnmpXi1R0VdM50jbVrLl9JJ1pfYhMn1eBTL7g/19D9mlav1Lp1NQANNhdhjGh64dczU@xN76pK0jhhkasUHFfABXC4QUAmV1EcN/njb372WbJeTwpJ@nWFPIQJXQTqUiDwQso8Kwl@7wzKB43uecnabvJLTTo5Vai0mxjZhgguUSebyqYiW7IuK12lCw6TyC6Rh/JQ6SnUbpMNIs/kGZFHjtIDlwF/MrhMuU/kAZFt2QYwiAWX35F9dPXhMYC/PiBy4c/ETVZdRdYJZGShkko/QaZ0MKV80SHvDx3Pz45bXJMkCf/CAANcVERZLJpt/AZGk3/xoiVttdVKmYjI5GKn@aKVbPMtHk9IVit50p0ZG60XPGglMs86A4aQhOeBVV9LSK2WxBoAyEZbdD7vdA4e3e10JBweW8RoZHYzIO53d@sg/oPHTqJR22lV6egRjiAJaXun1cgJ6C5mYGxQIYzcNyzDzkqZL3gtEMOzsUEJ0H5x9gKMoNQZmkJnp/A4Cx0fteDWYUYSjZbOPmrFvNQBF8JK0kcrMCw5oNS2C2YDWeh@8A/W5D/Uv/mP6//hM5ImqWY7nTqfb6folca/dPp8fj4P7o10KhV4UtvwhwHgxyTn8wY6KdA5uJqpdDs9n7MwuKfS2wxhA7LZbtC0CzgYZBJRljRbdkv9/T4h6@BqJWvkBb@97eoXrRqVBnm5QhL8ixrRFisNrdZUltMgsYLj2wWbbGoXdFo2XdPxQ4Wb3abS/qPv0yP6d9IUqJCv1ZQtwjxqXq3V8qGvVK7VyqFnM5WqXL0a8o5SBNspn0@nazXw7IRoZfBC2iZ5kyF10oJ7@/ZtlklZvbgIcebyxYyMKzy1WphTAbI1PE1n4hv00MPH9Hh7kBaFBEGhQIJJ6pRMv4@BYj3JV/nbt1PB54h39tK3b6sV@eIiChmPIUhZCup0eqbb6WB47uKC7/B0daBSAL9cvrhQ5EpGSZK046Ye4TdlIa@UoJBbaoNmWwGZreZLEB2UoLC9Xcw3GsU8hBTLkBAqxSR2jST5ZI1PnNNqKOUSk2N8DYNJAjo0jJre@TxBW5LkC@kUyMA0aJXzBP65KC7ZcFUopGt5WU6cz3kGrFQqDDpN8sVUOVMJ/uobadIAlYn9od6Xy@S3Slu7oEHjnzdddaFErZ0bdWVePzeq@HGkeU0PvtiJr48bt2/nKkCaspwgdyd4iEW2xQXiuA4DE2pfcGtxyWSG3LrN4bv1brJa26Utq5QLJJGssUAhCWKdlIHGkrpVUMpIE87s46EQoEJwCrVFN8gGp9In3rgKs1A3MBBs37jso/9cDy7SI10ywIsM0PYkJrHoRSzC4uld1yMgh11BbOSlafGKQozoYlPuuUKOcWmSPJjoJk57PXmwt39wnFW3BZJQ7@3tZ9Wnz@4kFPQWFn4anUP/0cHe3cfPIMGTBwd7Tw/eP/zw4NkTCPfI2eKKRolwrIjGjJhrhf@MfMS9dF9rhqEZE8PonE0mZ6/IS9PsmNC01gTq5gxc4hkdqNJYW1SvBj/d9LSXLzV3TC/y9ntfe/u9f/b2N7759je@9vY3vvPjz7/zNfj9AH7fZM9v/k6lgPcff/6Lv/X2138DAv8r/H4ffj/68ee//Cn7Uf8fwO@/x8L@IPjF4NiPA1w//@PPv/X9H3/@je/C79eC33ev/n7hR6t/3/nq@h@m@9ZvXQ/zzX8Pv99muELYb/46C8PnFfhfZ3Df@O7bX/oP7P@Pgj90/sbbX/oDvAWef/ndP/rvbz/7T6pa/qN/@/ar33r71c/efvXrb7/6T9W3v/xvFTl@@6233/ndP/@93/7z3/tX9P8H9P7b7/L/9rv/8k//zz/9z3/6e8HvR/D7D@D60Z/@J@iuf/W738P/b/3uX/3@9/D/f//Nv/rdb//Vz/9v1PErzPE3v/Y77P4Xv/Df/vJXv/7nP/r0L7/9o7/8ld/98//yjf/7l//bX/wvP/yLf/EZBv7Kj/7893/@zz772p999V//2Wefr7l/7dr75@8Q/vk/QMi7l/Nd8LxLvb5oyOc/VXn@LtRY5AJ8Atz9z9/@8s8Bg/8SIW@/9gN8DQN@a/5/oCoU5gfM9/8Dh3q1zhgjgwt@3377tW8iif5XIBH8R/T6euRZimGery88QNZfXZHon//483/9fepLGNUGXZbCkbysljNbYPRsVSrBaB6sWEGSn1vGFiEIcvo6SqiluK@jbHv7vU/ffv@fvv3er7z93s/jGC7kK9m9rKDcsNwHgIV3gEPA4rvAIeDHkH8nQ2fxhMzH4Nv4uFDO2bZd@/jjj7nOhYTv@@xekI/hj3wcXoRF4ftAQVQYh@H4ghCB8OaLF21cI46FSQpDLqnsGUTh7h/ISVBvZXYkRWVRxoW0yVKRGgTkyrlWrOhSv79VhT8Ct2p16zwr7LRAEaRJ55wRVkkJsG5IRNGyua2cBoBSnsGRqr0r5zOlLU0D6zaDeDNUFdoKFbRCjkwzQZbTYB0ZwwFoukWdU8KWAqY0espN6XIz/JcIKZMcITb7r3EkQ7UmeuFnz0IndQTpwqVq6uQKkE1msdBANUbClLUtFkIX4Gm@ebBQ6OpdZgoWOThwdhyi7oBBUK9nMGGdFRG8rDKNMqFFyWTqUG9MzdJkO2VEMb1DsUDKeuaIdLbqU5Ywg/gaITkyHAYd8YrKZ8r1u5BhfXqXIC5ETtG@eFFvlOvTBqJ7w6iTmWbu0DIhsnpm2ngD/jrFCem4xN03UJRyPZNplDFDrCRrHjTCsZEKtHK07rj6y9oAnrgFa2eXkFu8UubZGssGEoxB4z2zgEZAAIf4VmYrqA79D530t0UJvkGzCnIhLH6Hqso7THtGAMArCKIoEvjhxoYdsgvRU4YqQ7OFR4ZhyFCOoBwQBRBKEy5D25cRCPKHYPoFWKKq@RpYHzWCQa7O4Qfj6G4Zmduc4k6ocxJoynLwFdQ5pwFMXs5x5xdasFNqUyNzCCpyCEHzrG994QsLi8Ta3NzkEg0@xz@ma8MZSSLuSZXud4OeS@2oKuGLFR6DDbr5jxHvIW4gz3LUXcNqkreffj@Rl0sJbjNJP/9MWEbkVob9dne3yC0gK33GwqZ0W5mQyTl5J8HIuJ3J8Cpk2nDAt0VJmKHYuOckUcd/CE9QxiIJ8kRzTS/LZalIzMJDrCcwmjx@/DgoLw14Xucy0OPUnIJ@XBecTCaQ3OjhGnw2K4pZMZsNniJ90gAxcIg0NniKm0h6Erf3lFIZPzVr60OkC/fmzRvgDQ5pUT0EA5w5SV3Nl2kkoWwwxQ1f2ijLsQMgLGsW7itV8xWOzVYQpZgnJEU5Aq40wQ2UKWDtNMd2YTH2Cq9UUi2DSY2Q0GJiCsAYmqKCMontVKWvAZFCackLJYt7cQ6SzXvj5oBoiygrX6pcSIeR@4/J/uOHDw8eHY/bbcIZ9NPGRmfsOrrheSmM23t0l7GvWimmE80m1v24qqKM5A6qMrJx5vDu0eHTKmEUC5ouRetRo@vqAV0qCpcYjz/aTrg49@4aPH6xy@Gf4r26IEVKrYD8TicaXEI30CgDPsV/@NXIkTFA9n3oDe44U5KSszyfVYpoMqdxmRiK87POhOC5k@yQCpAOuJtPhPpiyRvnQmz1CQMa5EjlmENQqIPkKuXQUWIOpVREgMfsk3c5rvH04BgwHz8miiqL5MjpmlCoxsdkKtJyHjkjw8kKc5oaJdKxOXIQwqpbhj3wh5v4GWG@JfMxAm025Sz@qbkc3JV8MasUSu2NDetcQDwtyjLnuFdxDt5zAWnyHlyEe48j70EQXMKccM4Y34Rik/yHj2uMefH1XpKC0j/1XV4pgFxIc7heEeDjxvGrBkSHfra88MclNj75xCeNxsGju8LhPZyYmA5JuNFRMHviUKSM05u4Bo0dENIzPzTx425iz/TGljaDTgz02moAQXxcgE3M5/M@4Dy8R9SGSr0sbQ/vc52GdME9n2ocAQHd5xK3w7kYrnS7Wq2/UfIlKFu1@ianqhwEcFugVZj9DeA2umllS2J/vF3PK3JGCVc6SJrn@ZoHhcrlytIWl1B4Hh65XI6jHYhwVYMjdCvTG7leFwIZn1foTiYOPzSgTetqdAWw01sL2JzMYDEGIsjAd4kcxpVYXOALhwWoCu7tpd@zrQUSRb59O4czUrm8HNWdUNKQOTTpZi6fw0aCMAhtJ/KlYAkN6tdOcJbhk14d3IkWVph1ZiXBE/Sh/MuVZS7RTEDX5prtZv3/@792k2tP//H@A1mazTo3BQkZ/wXBCEOfZOmP4x46jxf/jx@P4t5r/0ePnYePnZED/zASPkQBXlv812pL3uv/A8mJQqkGqjDnG1NgJ/jLywXw/s13Pv3rX/qPf/1vvi7iFfiigL/5zrdZ@K/9It6//Z2//vY/@@tv/xsa8gt//Wv/Koj6m1/7TXIX@vjstQbjJ/f2G5@9/fx33v7wR28/@9W3P/w99Mb/P/93QdRn314EghtDLv1/m4q0fzwXSB/aw9hi8nZw9maDbvxuKpV8@wB6cJO0t8NjORsAvc3eIiJ4HkqdR/pLvsnC@IZnWH0Rt1PX@e1xIyer/HZwtneDfGjYKCGD9I1evefo9MvmtZ5o4hfm8SUZli6f52uOjSfq1cMVWxhG0@eD@hl9wbpm1AcintHi2poFybtObyZ6/gz0H92xHLeeBFswCSrkh6Zj0UYE917PsVE9s@sG2Ao4S76Ty@WrUD9x7Ix31EJJIEJTkUGnwp9SzvZAyrs7MLhU1eyGsVMqVXuibhmau1OoFjBaj9bZdwpydSB@/PDBfd8fH4E6YHj@Tr4CCfCcMzyRaKdcLRSgY/F8pklzbOMnm9noKWxswGhjaD0BnrgM7wlquV2l@dfryeROTlEFpZqTy1xQ2QXB7Jot5JXijlz142QkB5ZpO26W5/DLslErYAMOlUZezm9L8AT7V8I9AaArNMieMTBwUKctp2xLY@QJcAKoBs4uOAvbUhecJjgr25IJzkkjp8jb0oSxBjYBMXt1yAirk8GyZpFHskPlPBgyq7ZjG3OumtWy5jltrmq/359vnWcWHk47F5gPGnIuaNnueeStCTG4KplkBXMRCSFaH/jiPNj3UOXVQpmvNWsLf6nI19pzbndk9EwNPwXeks@vpiqCKsOwJiCjFuHmVddx/GrX6DuusQDMKcUQkBXoKkCen0fZtWTM8fxqdsUY0PT8KpZ8gZ9HqcJicfM5tCwSHcmfeP6cS2wdfZhrNIC1zvMlNV/IF9RcsVgoqaB@VfLFQhlaVi7KBVWF/p2vlCulOXQsSXqToJ@9I/vnYYer0sP@U1qVHWnZbJP0m0emdV7OCUxCpNI1GK8Tb7jEraMP1UZj/fxQClTZD1WhUc8VKuDKoUvN0dFdVQU1J@QUQcnh/w0OFf/fHV6FfxXvkCqncsd40M0j0CJBgbbJAzwnw3fIsePQt27uGPoaiP2hRg/V2Xcdz/s7wNzR7BMWdddkp8tGUfc1/DycNzL94RqIZ@MRnpFjuP9gGA5GXSggCmQGcAduruU4qwBK5NmTNbV8GJ3nDsRgB7oD@NHh@/ePY8/jg739@1yR3Hn86O6lRyEAKpAHB/eOI2@JxYZJCxGKnz148OCyN3jkHz876k8cF3/cvcfP8otbFIQvK3F5uJaBomCKJLihF5UQ1JXJBhitoUPh8D2p2/kKuR04C8WFU0bnR@xNLNOLXqViL/NVuePw9SyNoJTuGkRnRyHhbB49pjCwq5VShePGxHbOSEkmPceyNPzGfX8DAoeaR7qGgWaiZSEnYtZnjmv1zsyesQHKG@RRUfB74lgI7j4gGU10@nI9qOl46G0Pvz6Pa@Zda2KQyZisDYQHBqHTNQdDUAbOnBCA62oagd8XvSC9Eb/86wN8lgcNuxJjXQXnEtzeY7T/Kwme3@f5@5qv1Vyj9Jw0DqbAqdBvNHeWLWdzvF/gq/YA11gtMOibWxOwOjY28mXyF7/6g7/9w2@rLXlfxnnhvDrT6opU69aJUrxo7OSdXTRN0Nbd6hiJ8qBe9QpFZQfH07qc2U043n2jXON5MPhBglY9tPLvOW6vSg5sE@THPbh4HsdM/eQ5zhO2ajZYrtTKJDjvAaxXpVrbXcfVNdzvi7YhoZZeYCKKdGZCrZQL5UpOLWfLlXK@oBQLhayiZpVSuVSB4slKWSmWCxUlW85XQNvKVyC2UCkFBqYkbZE9CyeUssyIlLaqgN7W8Wva23SSQxw2uATbkkFep7Q0SWiRf0J4A9LwZM8eGBbgwLkpn74suGXWYUAmikxyJQKYNaKTxL17@zJW/A56cKPavszzPfQUyrJcusPzBo3ZL6NCyTssTRkPMOR95pHlO9CmE4YAz/7n@SF6Doq4uMDzJnr29xiB@@hRMT2AnbAY5rFCTwnAbPSAxUsRvIqwAdgeyydPC3qAHswSY@6xmH2I4/n3w@JgzBEDYwjuhzXd2@P5Q@bZ28OYfVrtAivol9GzRy@ed8EDHY7nB@AYuNDVgVXAid2O53Vw6TMNwvAL5ng8vO1rPD9j5EEC8fyUQmv6Cc93wnDM5sOgNAWkbpV6FFbrXeqp4B/Pq2GhESwXeXI8n488eajb/fsfakO/ZwzYNXPZU4ea3r@f08zp5OBe9/33u4NB153tHbx/hFH7@/dBu5lN3O6gGyTsduByINX@fVU7Gc0uX1Drw06nqlkro77c6eQ1@1JUZ9YxsISQ6hWULLgGmNGosw9R@/c7u9qqLTYUYQclzgieXbzujOB5R@uyqPCiUfQ57Xb5GnQDsD1aKQ7NJdwlg93zBCS4nR1puuvU0D@tE5nuRZ41i3K7RiPICOwduTbH@H4K7xrO/6bPZ81pXW7Xp/VSsMW1n@JbU7Vg8tmN0Y5SKVQ3tB1FzWemVXzP2eknSVJQdkhKub31mqQepXdUsHo2@NbOjsA3lfZOsfQcRVwVbzuqUq7mZZWkmTdXqkIaOSkTgrd0s9TeKRWqi8SlUkaT1GqpBMog0McHlaKLM64dkkqdGdpJOo1Fp1N2UB9acTKjlTZr/dQ0O62zQpJZujatKzV2RjKRL2FLpXp4IP9Ex5MTCEM6AIRTMHtwe1aKVyplHsogSak0CKP5fM6Ic56Xy/Pzc@/8vDWPRKUErsWk6UdfOT45Pv4YpBXoLLMsVUsbwXTjE9dAmVcLvO/f3xcPH4c@PGtfvIfqsuOK@yjjlmKY3hwGHYMRJN6HgR6s3jAM0viuY4kHdB8z6NxhRHg2hRiceyse31/C83TonLGcIZFXo4cn4hvm@CkCs0e0egNcWo@kaKmIlj6jKkan0ah36iNjNPZnUMUw1ZcJPad/gebQY2Wnn1LBc@ho8vO@64yCiE5dnsO4N01MBYHsgQY4cbOAsVMngvJi5PReqBm91sNvEdyp30E0tQ48u2C3G67ruDyYnXytv2PXJ7an9Y0nhouvzR8@3gTVB0@dSPWJkd4krQOE3keLaS40XGIvyvhoMkppQqObXg7CKfooAMmU@kpY/XOcooaS8/y81q@T1HMAfQV@d5OkeuKd9E6@BhS7QzppCJJf9F/0iUqK@Ro1jFKIC7ogpRRSQEvXG18GjY2hPiHVKpQmaPITwIqZAWJoDRqjpcfmvKbXLZISyDRNaZSvDepNTH6Bt20B1AxBaF60cYb9I7QWXk1g8GxAd6/NElrdm3Tp12yI3FVUuVibQphSyteG0N7a82nNrY8nrlGzwBvMyRNaY60GtAUSAprXF6m3P/dpelso1FlYjaK6QLWlI3bq05qN52MCp9RzdYjINPNytlAGjaZQyoIKoRazSjGby@azQglDQX/IFrIQCIYZqEgpK8UTwmflqSwqWcVQsin5hdl7kc6epGSgAyVeOus7B/ZkRDAEmgy5lfrhqaUz6haQqOcQbVugzAtCpob1AtoPydjMDimmI0OzWIK0QHJbKWszhUCbx5PxQbNdrR5Mx1@BqJTwaqeYKcmZ1@l0LbWRrnvGK7p@cccEBtGAuCiZaPXHG8DTwboF8SajJrQ6uJSSWm02u1jXkpzNyTmoptm5GGzzDb6dlTeKCrTZnM6iKYRJlvhUPWhO3CJs3EHLwTKgDZWKWuNEnCFPkDvuhK4d5MqqUJEKWwWZzdczFNw4EJFIW5Jq8cFLEMlUMllSk8mFmZ1O1nBhdINfrFRR45tuYE0lQWST5G21UNzhQQHkq3xF5QFsIXGxlEQOS75F9jXD01xc0@Bw6obkwXg/5@bn8@0GNxW5g5FpmVqW2KaOn4Uz9RORQ202S7rmgPQ1H/uyyO1BbQ@rIvcULEGDupoHeKQ/YenpgRGYrB0grNL1Hn84GxpgHoncjC5/@eLVUGglgs8wq2UI8iXuKZ43sK0@x7/S84d7j/Hv3m4C3zogu1@CuAqEl58/fPb42eN79J3yxUufX@Ta5YhEXy2Yip1aokbnqXFPAGTD9Pt3v3ZxPZhIG/jaNMmIgtigL@TvslxawdEw0gYhX/Tdh8x24zl7tvBNOkDN0fPEm6RN9yQbJhry5EMNFModkoQm19xRU1Vz7aZaArUEhq6mzEBVValBKToJ@g5oA/h7eg6F3s408LX7L5PZTMsIYdVvk8Ygsymrs8Rphy9WcvQd8U5DkU/IRvL2Fn5kXCCJ05ONhrqVST6p5jLJu8lcPnGaam02MsosKZGtjDrr4@4p3IUjJQFONbZu5baSzzLV8iBbVTJ4V@FeTRJhI7Hbye6mKx5HOZkklgi8Udmr7w2O9oJlBLK33yirs@C4gMTzDl8uBUVsbQLJ1Mzz3aX0DdCFnuNi4qV2Iz/FtYtbrpO1ZOI8SRLJeXLeTLa5xC492EBlBxuQRHS0Ae6BCtbhc/kiSSdIOvCVKgkvlab7EoKF8C8ldxNJXG8mnvcGmJq2Be3a4WviX36hgqBJ2E4Y4Ex8nKkFVapQwNXUhPRi7H2ilnMPDx/bd917BpdobVxsOLhSTmo8Q8mTN/YHXyFkDC2WJK16YlrPB@uRSqMhKNsqHghVIlVQAvpKUZAvGkyaNWhEUYWYtz/33fx0uwx@VVbAr6qFjNpoKFughibGbz//oe/OyPnBh3sPSBJXN//2D7@vlv72D3@TbuJOzumKp5orJQASnUqxlDg/H5@fgxI4Z3GFRDtxZdNaG8gkKVqltCUCL0hlDRwdKcFICupySUknPCERbOEvFoRUSpHU9FauLKch5iI4dCelymXwhtsOaBBfLPDpxMGRWVCV3e0dqNlOLq/WNqBZlei8ChL9bRteJcElyg9fXBACHr3RGwxMlbokKehHbwSy/UbYhie08Bthg7yoN3DnnYJHXYSL2Fv4wjxuKUk2MtJWkoCtTRrNeW3eztCFcDoX8nzLbl0iRmsDX7tcDtqy4c/Y8uifYVAvDfDAG/qMrZcen9pKS1KvR8cd3IQgCI0E63UdgxQawC9bEpRyK1y4Zn@C0Eq//blfVtXi3/7hL1x0Ljofq6paqVSKipr4yU@2J/bEM3qNn0DCJ@HxZsBEutlDZj12TgzbE6M5BzrYmTZ@6su0o7kKwo5XM4NUkUPUeS4xsdEeY/DhzAXOURDQSc2BbfTojAV3iho1bdYOO1Csl6JgWwQMkiy15@gJRukax4W2DrPX3IGepTjIFp7x22ynuXPuPYwC/YyAzVfj3luggoARaGSO3vGsiTumr6umaDqlnSW3IQnk8B4e1rYB0GkSjNsCSGIYq68kZUX2KNWozk3wwGs8@g3UEe49SBKciG7NyFhzPYNCmjboCiKC0HLSiF4T8m5D3hZL0KGhKVp7BpAlrHQskQ1mHPce6JeUCiaoncTcBoAayJT3gABQh1SA2GyTbZJLk3Mzk6ktzpWb43ki@OKmFh58xmEyxNYDMkWJawgHQWA@4ud1kS@CFga5FwsMkTAcbE9ZHQxQTE59qNCbwA7Td0YFuM6G2EK0auT27UWp6nWzlya0Roj/xBzjDC5tB3t1WQFZaMnfApEKKlUmg4393jLbAcUztLjAdQI7qq8WS0p49M45Dv7fmWmRIy81FY2oYQWC9mK9QgeSQWIkO2tDnWzXiaKW0iQqvA5l12mh6LE40fREa3pLVD8OI@dQwp8kwi9cgbA6js@KB3x717AuRhcRwT0CRtiEHtzoDzUmDHqGZY7M4CvxKPQO/TB1lAqqYloUum@6YArTrWvheXGpnJLGZIvz9Wg56Etqap7gq2KFND5oKoQm8NTw/LIgnw2qvuoONKg3dmx64JmPoglf1gOOABkFGTxyfIMVe2Kf4efograhieMlglqCpYOcjyWmB7g5tuGxtLgHrOsa2klImywxBiLRRz2iVkiKMpqN2yHsCF2aJqIF7oIFhTTuWsYIivTUMOhb415Vkgag@E26uJgtPTSBr4b3TBh@bE@6ywgsnZknpnSMx0ELTh9fLqfIAQvoitj92C4yMDYnVo9YjnNCLPPEYIsdqfjhcfgljGIWjJ8sUHbxA8JWUe1Vc1mcCFOyDAp@JXiUmLOcjaXdSM3SV585ZSPVwRa9oCOYCa1iGaeaHaMvvS64YDLFm3kcPSuvTtB4SIFfjEQu9Ex27FQSz51KpkWgfS@V5mj7epAEU4q4iDZO8Qk@LXpjy/Spkxu7xinByRAOxxgQmnonKAL2Yqjte3QAoH0PehaeX@e7VWi5DJTE7aV06HqBgLfJLZJTOQSEnBGUFQBwYNPXl7FDHCTFenh@DxpGpCtHKFegd456EIfnYwXsh@lD7kY3PU1wwd5kI0CHgw7Nq05Ytwg9hZgHewfyM636BkQWoYQrSrKR4jOANsOneYY6Sn85OeN2jsqSKrmKKUsQQ0BqwEJVBQ1FDj1cdvHdONz9cUfz2MdFkOuB6c/OzkR6VOPENUXDw2@peY6tWdJ4YII67Ei@MRoHX602dWkc4l24BPYJRXE8HO9MUamtV27P2JPj@l492BSaSva9JA6Op/ipsMHoFO0rKHDfowx1z6SfGdRTwR5Vxn9qO3se8l8V@U8oJ@eIhBBEM83OsnoWkGW7@km2f9arBRGntEMCcmhFIwzEA1Td0DPyQpc57kcQjo9yNIrqWid0kwFg4tmKwSJrVsMQchZ6A//YxL3ktnFG9lxXm6VofBqhkYFTM6r2kBkM@zQGnHje@jk7zdOcNmftpeTTKDkMatFWIBDkKRy5rkXKjnbF@CmLn0L8lMVPF5mG2TanbaaSYdAcq4Ncj5viQ0hEMwth5uwY1EUMxQx6OFEYCoScLYXh5lm9TlOH9GY@aMd6yBjAE2MguJGSms9bzVbb9oyzrXZGGgCz85QQ0OKAutmmND3rRW6kvnVqjR1vKQiGD6reBOXGIH0YcAPjFaxj1ECUMRi9TDy6cjAKtigxhSCoMGBAPQwiUTXY81NmuhadJUwjgXGa/ILGrGDNoDBtqn0FUUEYqEuM9IywcUTtGCIMj6oExYQYEvYc9uXMUDp85DoAE8IK9GN/ICJnJNlOAiUvdRUma2q0kWKlEoSwmEB2VFfrl6sSxkNTNC9Fxao5D9o/XvyNL1z8PvSL1aWnDMsGjBoX7yq4Ax5UiKC7UKqSRj3WrlACaUuzDBdGrgOmnwajNWSzJYVmBssHq@Cdmb4@TMUaX0@z9qGHFfA2X41YYVavQxVnddYtWb8IScoIHiXzgmSzkBGC9EyAAA55ZTIjSDaNJ5vW60xwkOmaZGexQk5pIacsCYOerilkO0gG1tNhOLxg87RBO8W9@TzgU9gwCmrQmCeedmrgvo6Xk9EYraowz4XMoVwQ8BCq2Mhnentl7s1YoWNC6xICZMQrCHrsI9xV7rLAU4TIF8koRspQRjFfwAZMVgCDURFc45gNFDEZtYFB4eczdByAvstnmhz//7b3retpI8uiv6On6EASkCNuju1k8GUWBpywlmOyASeTY3tYMgjMDCAGYRsm8f72Q5z3OK@yX@M8xTl16ZZaQtgkmcte65u99sRC6q6urq7urqquqi7QUQH@L8//JSz1Uv1XWH6ZD5cshF/mrcj/fpeXF0hZbYJq0kchv4ULshFYKnSTxVsXtMHADqE5TWiv8LAo/A4WgDEVYw1uhFDSpLjda14g@wJPcWYP/EhSVLBywhIl9TFeaKzEqUcpkKkRQdmxbkHPOB8nzF0tC7uyMgQboxBHteOq2KAwjB4JzkpoTkwTLKUwGo8H4/sQoNM9krxxEpHV4qlXhP8AB0uBBDKR/SJNtDEfxI0ocnndO6OkR3IiEJ@KdEHHBhHsgXI8xuN1K/HUEwnrGVQ0kXGr9SPTCKczl8ckofqAnDcZp6GWlchkE1QV3sHSiu/MMAgeTXyvEAaUUTZVihgqFHgDWpZu63Dm0JVx3yHFzM4VXuV3vjOod2NrZo3OvruwNjr7CQFLkD0eedfT2@7PfffqpieGYvLT5byz@PUXIba3MHhUbD7j4MDCzn6OgpleCowr/S5Pieglgt9ToCMmks4qk3ZKUAp69rh/LCgdviBfhSLKhBEuFRsjxYVoVJjtj852LvbHsAiPzsYXu2jWmD3fnz0vPE/ji2cFE/PiYM1052x2AXS502bRhvHaBq2GrqQsXXp0@Al7mhEyF8xgh/TwFJYOL/DmleEABH1ipltSSGXkGigrwLABRP1eaaPWQ82eylv4JNV7qJQVdYR8O0ChxP/g4f1sHu2weMQ6w7zqABKPu0DCoLTmsMu@2GSl3RHYIywFu3ZfRwJHHM0xOP39ZOlZQyaON7ir1Bc0juEVxAIVVzz1h526aBj/cT3o/Fx@LTbz@ZeF/IuCRjK8dxYRzGdfbAXbFRBJfdhEN5/twpZhlN3Jgh35YDNHWFsZBGiJY1SO34Ne5tw447FjlIZD9vjzML@/M71xulnDaDhdcia9vCaKoBp3jeQCrda9nnY4KTxdaL9AvsAbKyiNPEx@/IueiiNQdXryYjfLQCsIKGSjwYxtJe7NAC9f8C0/PXc4dG@RYB00ujA9sNLIgT3O2DBFGCUklsKF9P3RtTfDKY1WYwRoX@K1sB2fDGPY/DowMmTCMIYAigx3WmPjbgQTaK8ztFHVysYhAA1pFFAIQNe61x3nXhwMQuILcRCyYyrGwlYjk3OnhktzZWSjagtyXUBgGhWqpuEOA9x6U2uKZv2o9aHUqAp4fteov69VqhVx@FG03lRFuf7uI7npijf140q10RQYZlmun7QatcPTVh1eJEpNqJmgD0bp5KOo/vCuUW02Rb0ham/fHdcAGoBvlE5atWrTErWT8vFppXby2hIAQZzUW@K49rbWgmKtukWtqmpGUE/Uj8TbaqP8Bn6WDmvHtdZHavGo1jrBxo6gtZJ4V2q0auXT41JDvDttvKs3qwI7ZlRqzfJxqfa2WslC@9CmqL6vnrRE803p@DjS0fqHk2oDkQ/18rAKWJYOYXvElqiflVqjWm5hh4KnMhAPEDy2RPNdtVzDh@oPVehOqfHRkkCb1f84hULwUVRKb0uvoXNG@gGqwLiUTxtVPIlCSjRPD5utWuu0VRWv6/UK0bpZbbyvlavNXWEc15tEsNNm1YI2WiVqGmAAteA7PB@eNmtEt9pJq9ponL5r1eonJgzyhyrejVEuQdUKEbh@wr0FItUbHxEq0oEGwBIf3lThfQNpStQqIRWaQLVySy8GDQIRW3o3xUn19XHtdfWkXMXPdQTzodasmjBgtSYWAJjY7ocSNHpKvcZxArz4EZjVUJxr0XCK2pEoVd7XEHNZGjigWZPcQmQrv5E0z6KDrSagDfA6Occe6UJbb/nVjYNOYcvSXrz8558/leuVqkioc8NE8OEUdp1XkYMp/RvsNP5H@Bk6AOg6l9f9Nl5MghK7X42FqpHXtzDLgInxzefGPWfVUnajCslku/2@1C41XjfbbdNap2YIjYdqUDpNENbuKWXKPmKQGNrQUKgsFpnueyFCHTxDcbDnTC3BjshUkqn/jDbXsT0CXTGX6zqyGppCELASS2EPnrojAcC6uDSSFRYjsoMmSeqh3wPJDlQxrcBnO214jT3nQq4H/4w/Bz94c9BewOrMonQu13dmjAYoqKoZboQMTPSPtO@A9kWSvOc4P/fTeb05Z9w1s3iLD3pIyjpUduYMh/20@UD1S6cfqZ6J1idk0aipss56HG7A2gUyJp@DSZIJOS7ZKfUsjf@0Z/THVNiwBQ0NJdQUmeClQpR@xtXP8hdIVjYUgkTNg4wy39vSD7UPqOTmN7d2I@/f@O95bqHTIPqXwoZ3RvUu6M@bCy4AE4wsm0CSgbQ35nJaHRDLSKD0C99CwSssxLcQ4V595dC@DiQBQfYab4fT6sNuPB3MdexhHX7dKL09PD06gqUTsd16tf1yZ9fwDzF/sPjvR2yHPDzpDHcC@zjIafRJmyVlEHxopmju@AH7EwPnclgQwzvUoNFLtJr5V/2wkMB5GUiW2ntBN5h6GHxigxLljOl6IjJnPjYUv8bOTMkA6VBXTezNyJ6TiG@DrEQ8IA9NhwsatTn@g7D96a@muN8hyUCSxcjnFTjXeMTrXgIr0Ulbz70e8zEIFskmFB/zobhPA7y7SBSK8hiRfkne1kYRBFscaJyvNOxUE5B4HMVCSD2UvLuhiXdktZXKJZ3FwpsfJL/B40fpLkDOA7Y3K82aQMYjvybqwIGiKzt9JiFfYLgdHlGrlvYEWhBMiRTNPamq@mZWbTYQKhisitapMOBd3yobbRIV4dTfUqBvM6eiKRTh7EqOlb@Bc@O6I6HsKmus/K1sfIJh@SZjptqt34ahinz0rYKKnCEyfRM9CP6fSJMY@HugcQL0gFqaS8ValCSoTCtQX4kog1tlxNAsJwE19VcfAzB3@sBc@R2TlqE5uRIgCeToLNSLj@RE0kvHEACZ3ETPAm3@dl2HL1u8skF1@lvClNXRBjPujCZpIfcKtVUswc3sXFgkdlnKboM/TGGSYVZoDR5DVfE3VtwuadaDyhRR5cVTL8HgTGVNzW3geUYw4YlLkSIFNdkDzsrLWabWAXlwpW04Xf/8CcTSu5UWwQ2hORyF1n5pVVOEAtAHiM9yPynu0BWdoes5Ef8VTqTfIp8C9N635AVz0gEAPQ3QxQnhPO0KeXebM7vFDWLI0MnxIYAm0k/J9wIb4WOJQHBQy62ZBdLStnrrYz8n7G817E/HHGNCP4tClciyj4nEcIyX7wHP0C294q29AJSH63WbWSy30XQtcetQJA@bJWR9DMPsuO4UREcb@w04WoOFmRUfpNHBGXvXU@kNAvvZYCotEkroh2ZmdL050QK3GY7dINS8AcgNM7S5IH9Ql0aOPZYOIoN5ZkekgXkVjx4gC5Nby/x5QaT3gi97QBNy8iIi7okdTPpFpZig0gHLIQoOPF@5gFnicjt7Ih9Mv1t3@jPu/SgCjbtO1/fz0kDCCzVItTF5zHRm3PWJ65FFA4YCLSA@JQpsSLu0Oz/fouQNe/RLyU4goOOrROBrhJ5g1JMvb8dnUgkVGwoYV7YOzLeTgcFEKm1KRyvf9aqwuU2oxClcdyuVMfK9CpvEReJ87C8pRXlD5lMlOuITr5v@00d84hvSnP2nHs4eeIP2cymCIsIos6LNdnmdI/zwvOLDwJl2dZsoSDJde4LmN1J93DHxojIdSieKjj3znAVoAJ3cYJ4jGO30392rcbvsDu3@wB3YoKdheMWcVzx8XNAjDlh/6t56FGHMOX20Qt1F8EzWcHmojb@lxw7@DA46vZkzSetHILPpooQ5KFCLoWN8PGv19yvi70n0xNmvs7UdVPLryDu0r70r0E13V9Z9UYirzKcFCEAucAeR0xk6JnfQ53FfteRO0tpxhypweV8BDcdLkRG29vluJcbfAYnogDeEsUJm6chD7wRqZisxPuvOrS55dEzdGaxbFQfjVr00vbZsTCgJq8j3eApRFIVXea0qZWvsztGrAx8Wq8m9@fJPxh4Q@Ab0Cy/iuCWOEWiJ68nZAGsyKRPSZwtwIXfmAa3RtBLDKjbowy40DAFtz6NQw58Xq6hBp4ogFEmnhSWuxBmZBsUHE2Gk27DktBd0j3RKpExyFEARpDRL51czrKMzq@5fo7eDR9wcZpfFhaksIac1pFeRqgNUwhR1IZiTax1l9lB9eMZsbq47ahEC7ksChnDQcjemE0pyQU9sdZc4Hmu5U1iMExHqyVPJlDdzJ6k1qbdy7Yg9546jdcdcRaRPEWbbh81yo0uk3V/g42LXiOITYZowxegUG3gI1Vd69tk8SsT5fhvn23578QAdVtEsOJP1NxV/vLs893FTvMHQUrXR@FOKcEeXr13//VkbOt5evYJImKxetWnFaOOS0V7wowYqQiafSutTiLhP4h6hRxcoh@12gXb6@KwkavQAXjmQqU8hlyGkJ7rB2yMH16VJLwsdSZvqfMpfpHyBc24t6CivkLlEl038wABRKnYygR2KLbjBYEX4iGIteuk2ugUWcCWCpwP22VWeTxJRn2AU4yCNO@zee9ZeZAoXuwxp7kMCrYIvs74HknyFxc7ac4KyRAqY4jGk8Hu0tDZdrd@rb@0LlAMIXJs@e9d4BA/SFHYGb0/vXME/@qf2HGXgoClZMzSjwhOhTUsDzAXQUvpDh9VVlP4GU@Z4eEjLaQQKBL9O45/nsgY6R@/kfWpjlXl3gUVMSW6ebSYmOKMqAUPxbyS/nIos6pLiCgAcxhjq7xcAAjqJEfZ4KDB0erMQ54UQlWMEFfcLOC3hJfmYBT4kMd@RqLLA1rZWIh9X4jsdRiYWCAgW8WUCREBmiS8SQIGNLhYXrcTL@P4EJUAgVrzPFIehkKMSpqE/ckxASn6XN4MV5awgrLzkYPq4tW2GPvr8TV@/y2tf89GvQB8fw7NMIfr1VT70NdTs5ma4aqgm0MPUWw19BFKYOsL@qvBt/2eQS6DmQK4k3D1NyQhJGdL3C5MTgpYJelv2J0/soYnjQMkYCh4dxmUKpCoq9avNAWshF/f73dlFio4M0BP@m3urYjYUJjLyInU@Jkd7Nu6yQkgSawK3euwWarrkTYGGE/I4Af1W6bRuT7xvHR3pSrC4XChHo5Ez3c7n88jEl3oogfLbQlPSwM2FS@d618NhbnL79@n7yxyt/ZjDeei5RaVBOzAkMCm8rDvtc5wN4gBFsXQGCDxybxzU9a97PT2gBU8ocfBg2Lgk@4p1BW1AA9/p5X2LA@yPgg32n9hB7N8/hT/7bm0WNCUUdQwFtYF65zcJdXoG5MEXPfT98k@qCBguzMqbCfYtc//gE@4gGCdGg0XOoCaahST7J944w6FriQ@Yo@xxgiwqkQpHR3qFPBfBE0YkCroYDYHDLOHcDIbB@ZSHRXReR3BqY1JRO8rLHiMNGk6/Op@kE2c/JmBbgS4/x24@R29fSyT6CVO63q8BlvkQ0F6r9MiepDtEp2hh2OrlDA6eAKMXBStW9wkVMckmJmn2cGkkajy62Z/cwTgNXTdJFlCRATS81JMVxX3iJs7nhR7SMM8wJE5079paNe52v21p/LZl8WbW6623KlJQBQ/sF62IHFf2bQsinQHQDJTTD@iJ0ZX/yMC0PooEQrGAg6FPy@sOVmhjBcN42tn/5TZdKpXEk8nz56JUOoQHTPRzWBIVfHF4KCqYRQV/P9vf3N7e5TW3Yn6Cl4fq5Z04BBh8u2vnalqBn/BtHwPcYLsnLfJJbv@Jtfukvb93sOvlzkqHF7lcH574BqNcSf7Aq41yh/Tj7Ee/UDabzT3pfHry7G4Xf59VLlJPLs@eTC5S/V3kMiBD6Xrm1mYZO3AfzU4vjSTvAtpb8iNVeraHOVplVaHSI4zs6c@wuhRFsuPlkvKtx3G4tMYmO4723hljIhRQ4VUIR1SVNzBEfmQv0BwPo9Nx0AEP9hugJOCCfqBcn89WlOF@7GoF/FOVJCEgZdYbB0DjCccCOskNY/xAZjD2nDFawG9I5uXuGYYNfweztuTf3I/yJoKN87TYyIsNS2wkEvQHbyXYODef5AZ41wUX8@8rCI4W0M1QeAMS9Eh/oMjFCLkN4wkFQCIkFQ5NhcfXo0s0PivtD8MnZfi61zce0VWMbCKhQyaskvz0ZHwHw/IJStwljEcUzljA3B8sKLSlFkONaScq/viiCGR77AgQtDxighRdaBJP@qAyn/nl1Bs51gbFZhJgJGvj9RHNe3wBe9ETiuksRHQpDBql4Ed@i3vjLgfvEtr4hdsPEKADFVYn8xQ2kkqm8KwDIyiDXlI3BcV46v2TzMe@DgtnhhWD5v9TaExAnx7phHsypnd0jkkfmf6JgX@8ojWV4LIUbc8nM4ZWZXQ9nA0mQ3nmRSTCkfNbu@OZhCNKgBgOR1AXl2cYGQow88GtQ2HI@rBw6PFCdF3sOs8EmYAVp4OZ5ZMjjQi5H9Mwtz9H5raZGyAmih2YBwgp35WvZw@GHpJ8pjK59u3pJeZaoITNYjDjczOy52FenQjGbs9HOkuQyeU8mM/QleRkavdHtiWSJ25rai9qsG2B5DPrZE3o4Tg1IyRw8smm47qnEOYeySEhivhdIc8hjN4eLmSwOY8tjgYNBg2pmgoyQQNOghA7ESWdz6GxitAx4OovGAQd5aXF2z@NlEssrbzoaSQhBV2Af2iaLU0dQ7Wgzx1/4iQMRtWfmYoXZKVr3GhHdPALK/nQhb1Xtk01HXk@KGC5xPZxd@o7Yzu0OU2GhsGJSZ7kdgXvizifKbEHeyPJO3QKLwtB/gDECuTIH0MJbmSmC7fHMpvxKJ1@dO7J4Pikvo@g8Jz1ffFzNrKqPCuncPARJeU7HQ94sYzsUAOmPTBhVtTI8x8g9IZ2H/Bb3NoLZMXzZPr7xznz7Mfz8cVG@nz8@fxXkzCRS7LaZTMiKQ@z1Yol5wrsjDkr9FN5pXmC74EX5@NwgfMxuXXx6b0kASCSS5/9mLv4nAOEzpOmuZE7TzJBQkOGmOTuby@H4HNLaCbDWOSSxiNzw1SDn/6@YArYW@kvjiG/MPkvYKGUSjLTg54z7QEoigGiSwVQscu92sxvbRa2QBPqO/PM1LnG/TbjXV86cxAlPFRnYes5/zXEDSFC3M09exdezqGfg/4Yk0PTiHoyoYVcQuU0p3YMn62gTpZ5AsoDldNIAgxxMf0yNh4@osJvCWA5VZYyWrDroMZ9adw/PXeE7dgermvR6BDmSPQyYB8RMqFmELJkvJUcaqrpkqJgs6woXzkwyAgEhjeX1HaLsTvOSGHNzKZ2UYjGqJkh5vaNztGlKRqaoU@kMJV6LAoH37/87/9d/yU5Sx5s5j5M4e8s@Uty51WSH@EBfr1Qv26SB8k9LLZzl1zkQAeGx5f//X@g/sHfAQ5@WezBPwfbCtbOInmQ2acqn5MHO/BQ2NyEdv/vf/0X9OEJa2yY2eZJ2xKE2K6iSNkeE@/Cd1HDXrJamgqWlQIuLAiDPQxBN4cf6Bg133yVJzNdUnpV3KD7z6A38/1R5BZPjlkzchViS4bypwDJiCvsYwMZBqlcKHpC891QbhvIvAGa4p9PszseaAD/lO4cfpO@68ZTD12GnrBaBAOY5hZBn@eHg/z3Cd@9o5hQPiW7SoRE1U6uta9e7AI7vHOd2aAT9pJQ03XUsW@dyyzyYdbpXoNONfaG7k/T3A2w5Kiw@SrXQ@N@jvy4cxOClJkssr@CICizkYBiSE6nlpjCCLgj@AvPmKMEBPoj/0xKZecAKXvidNiGFc7wBEWarUq10bD4eBi7kw1E6TT9CwI85iGRaTW0yPPzMdSsN4oi8dwvyOVI5zURm3fkHCuTjmTYG5Yy2IIAQ31A66DqT7Y07VMQEtWaAgQukrW73bYtv6WNRwkVeG4Zj66c4WQ/Qb5h0Bu86wskdEl/FjNXQskM0IKQydBCh7BGzswGFX0/QW9QHw9amOEdBnzWSroxrS4@WXuyrNTqu/tHeKZ1T9O33PQtjChKCUE7Ps8EuXDGQi/Ga8s@miqnThuP1GIbhtY8lQJrmqU/iIHHw1LrYViC7A5FQALVgu5IrzJ92CzShYFHbh2O2WPTIucBM5JB8KOlSgBn1U6yKDthu1luDBaIE3fsFNFDme9kwwiIfZW0ZTAmAWjps4odlmCoD/WJw2gqQmFHLLktjWE/JIEDYykFkGDgeLypBT7YBu8ePmgJR0vok0DDS8JEluoVSdmigmo4ipRUixtHzYztVGcd4Sfr6clcQLg80otEvrD5Ymt75@Wr7zBm/JHsbTwYrJRFLWByZQMMkqjToGTj@/39RCrBrzCh13KTCD0OLB7AoVvXrUlY8ePj/UJeAssnCNYtJabi6tJcSSADiFMnizsC6CjpaSKd/r54hh27OO@an@G/hKVqM8OhqdkeDn61mfTaOLzjgAhKczRyRu4Uj8dxYbYpswvm1YcthL/oZR2313Dwsin0dWW2h4aOXReDEqbudf9K544sW/tFCyYMEHw2XRRJg3rtcKQo6dQaViiLSoNDTYu@2FfwzpZ7gE65uCWgzMfAYZrBZEAvf1t6muLsSMEmhHkeMGIVjxA111GdnYk7x66onlSiiMlMaAPPh5vVPVtBuIP9EMBX60eY@UjrbguoC1OiL3ut1iSLDfqk@8oFLo/lgCuQ6TFWuoNpvTSqqLWa5IZZ@j6yFIgXB35Cu6AqjCPiFQOzkH@YlCquVfUCCaIWQmlN8hcxyz/P0UkW4KQPMs5T5OVEUfMRfTvwPMrnLRtLmNKjlArBQHp8KhEHEO02@QR3JF/EEaXHKqWx4tHmG0jJZRJv7eQB9jVVJ7bkoCdNBRQ1zplFfFpg/2snZUtUqvDP0YeKhYLyYekf2G8/YdZqfAsS30JR1I7UEBBBpRmOfG7RZ@oXDFECZslbnL4kQBAXXzJsYD2SvJGC1dqRpD1P6rPQ3L4IuALZ1ZZCuLKOykmCWVPIBvJIKu9kOpO5FqVCX2Tj1fJK81wWVtOCTVz3T2yNJo@CVn1ITMo1QGxGQWQUiIDbHwUMzx7oJHnbUndRjF07iufpEMuyQgVi@1EOyB7m2ZWUuY8tNiVbbBZxHO/jC@Lbe3mD7y4LM8cDvPH463gjsz5zZP4tmKP653DHC8kdL4q49jB3jDtTh1YkiuikpHZuDMdcLmgPbncH/QHah3raT@xE3tIA0IJHl5TZFA9SyGPfViwnIh3/4Xl0P0Inoc3tHeMrO78lO79VxDWXHivO/9TOZ37jzm/Lzm8Xca@JGXkp2snw19@ux4FImA6/iB1eFHe5mPm1Pd2RPd0p4m4aM8x/eE8zv1NPX8qevixixgQ@cOAUrvdzM0sipWa5VgvcLbIqA3EaswLGc6WJuhfe2GyJ3vDau9pHaV18Nf6vJP6vcDWipwaS1dZilH1dntVTDpZnyZKv0sMgK@4J91eGeun9lRtWoI/IDYoXaTJsTaWiAgK5xR@D06ZsID8Gq6@/@ayLM6/tlFuJM8NqCjRrhAUzmOIs@VJhlYD1ETPyDC1p5Vbj@Pn/YjKM7J9lFBogj0N7i/cMyZ1EV8FwrPi17IzWHYTdlDpHiFUkOQnZmYz29tnl0epVjRJbRPbFeCWBj9o4XTJmoHI0DyAyGQFtsrK@0qrQNVepF/wG@s6F4rsse/xVXPqd5NLviqIhFYNVpLKlwU/yYqCnbW5v37cHcK0s/sEJmLeg/D2z6v8FhwvL7h@lHlKn/dbxvKSWLMrQ83RzGYFlRLhM6RrKTIt4Zcz4Ev0P3vvJpzYNLdsyKCueYZTfVppou7AvO12n178a/PTzaOxOfpl6s@ub2/ni10LCMFRy/rTJWQuV9400Uyzna05ME5GkzRkta3MAAg3zKbaahA0hqUIhZZ4Vi5sXpsD5OeJ8THw@EAAgEXXsDfGeJHKz8LOH01CyB0M0ttejo39vhjHnQLL00B5ddm0xLwr0v84ULIHeYPJtBwgJJCI7TLoDq@fENE26F0ZeOZHSIRdTlv5T7@q0P6qxfU4kEhIl@FmjAwE0tvhFfQvNGZlcLsQGMB9/GXTDlhK2yfg1ZWo9VAskn25uXZhFINMH@oIMf2UPZ3wimP7V9D1hnJkfSYBbZ5kXOdxF8mYocEFDeo82QL9jpmSO4JSL@6utq6HvWjs@jLMA/EWocIhW2o/nMPX90B0ABlPBPXTd4TGOr2rBktSwxKugM0EmRAxrfmMPe/4oqGzFA3aqDPFOuI@UQxapHRqYCCEkMXr@ShcEU19hs660FPv18bABML4kd4UlUDq@WGmpwBKX0BoayulDm0a0Hg@vN@N04jGdCJjzzEeCckQH/Ka9T4of6g0Y/Rt7OkDDFlvbCtBG1snC/OyTw/9MTqbYREVycm1uw7zyIdMMM5eQi@/TKpTTyy9B75UvsQFad7ADeJ2u6gLuZn3Kbvgw0mugfM90DnEog0X2PoLtyGdvxdSFHSnUpVKItJQf46ZdmLuRtafoY5x@FRlsRQecXjtILvXiguWV4PMrHGfMOQZ7wNRmd7KkOJ0NYBFfBD7NJNyQw5guZVESIgbGufmjE7hzZYlL@UPm15GYaosH0oby9F@ZQaLxFZ1TwM7YHeO5eIln7sQQPkQQ4HAGFMy4FREb83/mxKa5urtQCvvpLQuWkS6HBjW@u@61jkD@wX4G5dUT7CH6Or5EiMFFmAWWIailVroO494gPy1zNh5JtduY@6fdplQr7TbKD@12ilthYUITgrR7L0qX3etpZmpfjWx7/Pdcx/MyeBX3ZGYYHSDr3p5IVU8qKQy18j9lJwsYh8xGRsg8/YJEDnxjJBLhKNNysyma5UbtXUvQN4PGpOMOh44UD6SMVJ928Y7QyqAzU2ITS3nq18jGtEIGXUopyp7XJFy4hzi47Ta6/7fbac8Z9rTRSQZP8N@b1ttj0aKEg61qk/IhNmOKIowsBkCSeoqI7z2u1Mutj@@qQMXR8MDYU3@g0AHV25sNZkPnYC/Hf/mdN1ugKLCYOKAFync5egl1c1x5Dy@@hj/dwY2gT/sJdfRfnDogbg1unF2orNOWEOy57ixAMAf1EaiElmMEVQW9Mghy9UpdFIXdxSMbEASV8oCTysPAkEFvIVIvUtmBR3p92gy3LG8@kdJoin9mscWUJVK3z1MxW394IJpvSkDL18f1w9IxZvx6V21gGstVY3HZbwPToARL1zKkwl85PM0dh4QK@jKTEmv0Y7jUDyQah999DL9b0Y1G9XUN8zmuxpxJui8@5YuFu/CnG/Spiv1Cl1DQt7tlDFagcnRcen0vFqjULe179BUtzLFfVzRVP3ldxxSUmDpzVYvuuA@aRr@NLceQV33Gptt4UYe3Fr1Vy4f1yj007w@5M9FGsTGcHms1Va6fnqxeHKSLcCEMJWn4iJ623p22jHBNf7GCCUPrlCXm2lKlTS3pkzI3V8E/LDWronpMGU@1T@TrMnRGCrolFhYvKqCC0trpeCC6WCpRIYoxxWhcM12tGrsc2ZegP1/PnF2MAy1@upvMd2fuRD7gVMMcv0WOdU1/uus6fXP33Ph0l@C29xPA0ImDT3e8WJ2PU3wVzSwtEdUn8xLePtKmESFGpdqova9WFD2a2udQSSBaray@@vTqDKYdjJvTKEb5ZyyZfSZmhNJLmzB9IcozhBSBYMowGH5Gv6v@FL1qMzTJ4e3upYubH@zC3cG1V9zOP9316SIRWWqOQVr64hhJuh4jJ6gOo3fZn9jd36xz1BeE3bi3QyDWglZ6OcTEFfDf8Hfv4LkhR/TSnc3cUYbSWqvh5Vqh7ziZQp99ADC5VtfGjzFVoz35GnIvkWwt3lLTjFI7H9XKvMk3QeovNRr1D83IarjEl/Z06t6eTn4f1hR5NW7wJClIq5hAuglY1wZdcW7QKkYX2M38ecm1tGIxhXgoZalzg8vpzI66BGFi5jbpIsLg1zdNZiJaxb0d/0uSDXeP35VmYTo1sNIfR6igd/fQKcQ5Kwml0fwP565jaPtfkmg6C/5OVFu95lHK9nvXvECAaVV/aEWFFiQ/3UutUx5ffB3Bl7dfvWuBQEgtrGAPia@Pdrz6ds8K3xsMh6sEX1/Fmy/Ly1KiXFFTU//mq@TlRrVZP35fFZXa61pLvC8dn1YjYvMUz4ZuHD7Ilk1NnT5eCAH0oxMqreGUpkB0MLSC4uD4HIuC3fA0HG1GPd@gaYmew@Egg1nK47KGblH18/2M3bET25JqItDLi3EpnqKgoVrqcwqtV/QlXOcWbwfdl3DlgdDnlBk1vUMx6daTQsMMB0uQty1et4r3WC4bhIfShsajFKJvQFkEXLgwlxehq3Vrb8bVlqSIHBWCRHNlRszz4c55oNgtd25zuXNAsG/qnkQQ7VpZaDQN8O7HrON6fzhi0ObDiIFW@EdTDaNaQpQzI7r88gkFuSCs4hLZ8BnNgvBpmAx6@4ezoEiqlTBO1KRdWlFgWXtwPVlniurnqMFB6vwxKvHW0gQ2H5rCZXe4PGSFlf1LTfuXoNNb9P@mv4vEnsVb911yEX98b6041b8PkHnPcMcuhZFNoXZSqb6rnuCVNOIf1Y8f6o0KmoSb0a1BXvweGULfE5tMqJ5uc9YNrKoCF6NsFDNX3RMFcsyVGLodmBU4EmQso514Hhw1MngOfoEHefNy6KRYHcTTMkHmjFSYGkswmE3E8jpPx8zcIQS3tcwPlEnzvsnL1fF6iqW6izXrFmLqYn76ddveXFF/3fZfxNUnyywbi6S9CjHiP4sVQrS/XupDhAaYVQN0/yRfGj7z9x1A8e83gmT9@sbxU0anP2oQX/01iP7/XU7XrLwVV3m4ZuXtmMqzdVveiau8bssvVzKub@pc5l5LRC12X8DO0u7214r0J61Iyu5536IUP2ho9/tr2P7MYSPL65cPHBki/xq5P3Pk2Bb85UOH1tC/Ru7PHDmyR3@bBIeGyMggkoE0ih@q7lHswu2wewXaNQlA@ON9IiRaNCMoBNZMJ70Gmcx1G0N18usUwq/V9b6W0dhpB63e0mwtlMe6ZKzixapeh7033peOxdt6pXYU58GxRCDP@cOm9CYp@j7ZAksufiTvmzij2bTNpuW1qSpigaCToD/mGN4fO8nQL@lMFb8g27BsP8bVmv1l/XrmGr7P0nP3dupi/LmHNyypEO@RPdM40LejlCp4qfJx/bQBA9tofsFE77q/z8C6k5V0ZBPn13D/DTvoqzUwykn@4sqTOtozWQoxg8/PU/EO2pqpk2JpekPXDlCjt5jknl8vmX7DbWS@pY3Mem1sfEsbG@u1kfuWNnK5uEZWLEuV6uHpa5ETzTf1D/Fl6It3hRdE4e1OnanjjFctYeE1DOr8Prweazn/06yAkR3CHw1/dkQqPWi/l8vRzyCd@PdY6IuQNjg8fDw6g7FKobzW8NAFaH/g@HzJfhE3RkwVPqb4Tem5whZ/Uj/JkAE@ZIjnO@x9z1bdJO95mCRQWuU993ra0c9TKDUtjhF/CTLTppcip@7dwfA2pbADLYf4YJyXyvdAoa9CZRLlu0Hi@ZYdU5/DgMc2EvjhfksjvpfrUjuhhUmJJ8Sd5@P4zSS@77GLZeDtfLbkAHxxlkKMUheKIYkQsWCSOqBMJoNVPqWYUVPFT3cgExIoeLxbjUeMB3AsrrFez0slV/syL/N90Ly5kqBL4xwLLxJy4gNfdp02V8SP@RNB5mgOsYc8R6LLI/SLJIr3HrnNQ6mcw7VFytIjeVaSk4/TAlnTEnNYgvDfuAV/bZfx2Imw3gDHO4Zr15TRZcLGynlEy/1QHa4mY@ZSLIxwtTiJDU9@geDx1F6xOWp8vRSMSBwhtQA@Y186TryP86lqHFs/cOofWR96SrEIJjaenvtTO5W6W7E28Byj@v7lCUgVC4huxsUp6rgdrEKNkCBtx5N0AT1zdUkspMUrpc2V03dCWecC6KvnltyJJ0iVE3fsfAUJ@e@DRIzhwPAE9v1N7CUbiaaU8dE2iRUZEisogMg/46bshITqt/J0mF1XocM6Ykk0qqWKaLYa4uj0pCxqJ80Wvqgf0Yfj2kk15lRnET8s@vanCH6mqH0RpH5ce@UNA@IN8V9pFSZtXhFcjr30dCNm98f@AS5/YI4R7UPRWnGURfEynrBqhIoP0yC@4hnAvggU8cHFvYAGnBPj34AL4qlxP188qA1oGsHYFd41JvXCzcSZgw7ipcx116iz4hYvS7hX/0Y7pSYgxO6Uq8WOmMUoTlpeYc9TV2J8wcAxCek@@BjZQqqZ6pYMY@W8owKFFXa/wM1JLghRD6fQ8ET0t9IhrLqlcqtaEW@rrTf1StP/FHHmxTjdaJTucuibFoJrRoLzU5dO/3ocjTGl0Ldxd03IHDsbG9aapVxN8SGv2c7QBRotYUS3v6dWRuuVS8fHpcPjqiRNNGBv7nSkHos5f9sTe3YV7QGrsSri1i8Gu/00Fcn@8ioVRU@HEOkWDUbkXUi3lvUiRZDQpvFQ5DnHiwPSfry2bCpIjKOVyzIdgtQ2poGZRQ0DuUBkOiJT0APSH2tRx3Sdjkybzq8tTI80dm5pqtl@Ulrjf0Ig95rhlXkZXZmPC67MU2wlO/VTSPRuEGOZONjKb8t48IfiwpnEMtVROMhfTNzhoj904RkegOK5rnOTG18PhwZu@d1BrxceBP354Nkm3ojpdK5cAdj8fw)

⫸fuck is a trivial brainfuck substitution, I use custom interpreter:

```bash
# Based on /opt/brainfuck/alphuck. Uses ruby tr instead of bash tr to deal with Unicode.
ruby -pe '$_.tr! "⫸⫷⁜⌁⁕⁑⟬⟭!-~", "><+\\-.,[] "' polyglot.poly > ⫸fuck.bf
/opt/brainfuck/brainfuck ⫸fuck.bf
```

The code:

```
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕
```

#### Related stuff

Since the rules are more relaxed now I promoted abstraction tests for alphuck, what and ChuckScript to a full interpreter status.
So now the official interpreter for alphuck is the case-insensitive variant of TIO alphuck:

```bash
tr A-Z a-z < polyglot.poly > polyglot.alphuck
/opt/brainfuck/alphuck polyglot.alphuck
```

what interpreter:

```bash
ruby -e 'hh = Hash[*%w{ !!! > !!? < !?? + ??? - ??! . ?!! , ?!? [ !?! ] }]
puts `cat polyglot.poly`.bytes.each_slice(3).map{|x| hh[x.pack"c*"]}.join' > what.bf
/opt/brainfuck/brainfuck what.bf
```

ChuckScript interpreter:

```bash
ruby -e 'puts `cat polyglot.poly`[/\[0\]\{(\d+)\}/,1].to_i.to_s(2)[1..-1].scan(/.{8}/).map{|x|x.to_i(2).chr}.join' | node
```

Explanation:

```ruby
#based on the python impl by Potato44
#import re;code=open('polyglot.poly').read();m=re.search(r'\[0\]\{\d+\}',code);a=bin(int(m.group(0)[4:-1]))[3:];b='0'*((8-len(a))%8)+a;print('eval(\\''+''.join([chr(int(x,2))for x in re.findall('.{8}',b)])+'\\')',end='')

code = `cat polyglot.poly`

# ,1 # the first parenthesized subgroup
n = code[/\[0\]\{(\d+)\}/, 1].to_i

# to_s(2) convert an integer to a binary string, 3.to_s(2) == '11'
bits = n.to_s(2)[1..-1] # [1..-1] chop off first 1, same as [1:] in Python

# convert each 8 bits to char; each_slice(8) can be used instead of scan(/.{8}/)
js = bits.scan(/.{8}/).map{|x| x.to_i(2).chr}.join
```

Answer (score 0):

## 420. [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 18314 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyq" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>](  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2"  );print(349)#\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print(not inspect.isfunction(lambda:2 )and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0 );'''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+    =x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +     +8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ? R`"12"`"420"
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ? R _`*` *
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.  0; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Ex Crithary,8,3"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   Ford: Eniari^ x._,_  \;ncepp 
 ; ;:在ｕ
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({b2dacd6d-9154-4b7a-92e3-36dfae43b161}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rcyPLdSD4UXHL8yOSBXbjWU@8AQIkm82@zat@UGz2vdcC0OhCoQDUZaEKXVUggSbRca/GoZUs2WPLkkd@Xlkez8orT4x3YmYtx8g7EfZE7JcJx3zyD6Bsx27YDukfaM/JrCoAJED2le0NxxZQVfk4eTLzZObJczKzMjuaN/jpT2N4kUPHmvYtxye@4fmk65qnhiuSe1Oyo5leXs1yHELtuv3x0LB9r8LFiEKIpdn9sdY3SM@0fMPNEM8wSMewnDPwVwnZGttjz@jWwZYlxDbOyIGtm13AQHznxLDN14YLfjlC7hvWxfDCJ7ozHGp21yMj17R96psn5FADS2@snxCt4/mupvumY4NXYSmK4pKtRMhjx/UMwOTohuc5iKu8BKLI5F0N4htZxuQKZkUhH5iG2yU0FSPXYGlRVPL@8YMHV12z5POCY5MHmMIrXjmyO/adA/8q/jzZ7Ru2RlSxLKpXPQtAJ9@wSnJJvupVhKIyfFO/Gk@J7PZ6pm2Qx5DXq55lonue4OmuOfI5KErywHShmLWgOImu2VBsWKgpYgxH/pQIrCJolhUVskc0j4y9sWZROHs87BhuCOj5muubdp@cmf6A@APTi8JRaG@k6YbQNSxzaPpGl1gmBHJ6ARZAbXfJiTE9c1wo@wCnY1tTCGjoZs/EIGE6ACFeCX9gMDxDbQoVx/ahlhCNeJAMywixJbkYwN83OuM@ccb@aOwTSFvX9LSOBUg7U9I1etrY8jOkA35QJNT9bGDYQa0GdCKgOHZYqj4a06QZ88qvdbtEhgoN6TgxiAlUo8mqkGwW3InjAtUAKkxRgIxWcJZHYwIlDGXWcyokL8vgvx@5YGo1y3OCxCwnDT1taLS0zBDvoev0XW0I1OgalKbvHxwST3dcsMGNsKxh3YRG13yytUXi@0/ux0k9KhbR7XBREdXIORRBLPQkp5o1hhqyWBIOlI8bheawyOIb8QqJA1lUmeRyJAftt0TUPBBJkctgAEagZhW4C0QtkZwC7S1PsgCcVaFxF8AHGgTJyfl4BiPvuVrftAyGuo@oi9h2IIwKTzlHstAssoUsg@47Vo@B6jQVRZItkUKRFPOkCM8yKauQDIwzBy0mD3cBbsBYhjQCIjULKZZVhmzeKKASY0XcIz1taFrTIAYahU7yCikCVsiMAtjVEmCBdzaLdxbuEmJbvhZx@wMoioF2CugFyzxBXmZE7AzLV4KXlEpJlG8iY2bRewOMHugKFM2XSBGiLwBFcpAEILtagujzMsuINzAsKwg28DAYTW1RhhtSXgRalKBoZKCpjEQtwg12YJ0q8EgVGKIKPE4FvqSqYM5iFACHZVWAci7kWDQDzTuBiFg8apcWAPB9QKMgxZEfKkgkwAClRoDUUAdyUEuyWEvyWQLph7QUCwRqQEkhpRwpFQnQsywTKB8F0oVVSAFWrEB6FEQG9UCBiqBAmhSgtgJIlWyecAvEVrLoD2GzEBZIo@QgTA7MUHBKAW8IB7VDgSgViFNVy/MaCmlT85DffJZWXbUApVsEP6CbCmlVoUphfVVL4I9hS0DDEtbsYjzDCKEhHaBUsC1AXQRi5CE9FC/AglktBpVXs0YDrYOMn4Xs9DBoAdtIAckIQWXMHrxzSE1IigxosDVA8lWoAVnalOCdi6K3FEDSQPRG16Tc28IeRIkoVMzQCvmRNvLnZFMKNEWjqT@I3FTm5gBXNYEzGn1Nn0ae0AozkefctZBFV5Uy4jkiOYeuHrBdZ@xZcySRIafSqIxT05q7lahb19C6PdMbvJmnNUcj6Riab5sn81jy@cwCUbUFjwJ6LDkVs4uwvilAX9YfoGmeF7WIMCMnKqClJCsKTV7H6I3tviGUSwvpoz7@2PWh15nHWWbOrtnvQw8@x6NkaDZpLzp3ztMUWtksdO6hI1IX43RN6NvvEn0AsknkWWb4y@U5jqyKOKZaB7t8AWQ16CLK2Kn1zAnp3NVplzJPYJbSSR@YoxC4shZ4oXBpJJNSYaFuUMq9LskRe8arJX7kmHYiTuJJbsZBR8Tkz8VuHHq7D7ALw04Zqy50ug4VKebsM2GH3WYSiLYsAUCXbKGk1DF0Dbtn7KwM2tmGeExfJBAJCJGGc4rCLe0xl6LxaK/acVGWBRGoa7guQVgQgL0M7X@9ccczXo1RyJqnqwcdugH9fk8zrSgBtB/RfCodwDvuQXzT5WT3XGdIO5sh9q@W44zWyDLQm58hoofOmTFP@ryz10YjC0QqcDeYRAeJOdOoVE5F@MVYWYIgEIaDAgeENCoQRUzX0Cntg6xD6CwILctJrBC1fjeLWO4tyFpZaCwgh3gYxh5bVgWEIEMn2brUNU4ldGHy2LIchmkIJTSQswIUHQ3Ebkw5TUWE6a4qUtnvOCxZzxkuZ431rwdR1gcmSk3WmTaF0utB12pMtCEoBwQlcGi5ZAg1hpUglgRoEZitA9J17LgfYTlzQcKFTEc5oVI00sQ3hwboSA4EwRLP0URj705T1plCVabUyolUKWIpuUIokbtKKOaQW3BgjQVkwe5YR6ph3KZNaxCISx4qAC6wSubG@S5pNjW4XRD2RoEeKKIBAZ9h0hbUCY@19kAs1ylGFGAN2wMNxROJiVoa1Py@04PKdmZC3oFhQdA5bp0SAUkQOU1EXeQoybECDU8sYhJ9NCLgDp0SVM8HcgnkU@cjk7wGT2sA@oU@dt0pmYygJMwhQPm60@tB7X1tjAaAggy7RJ/q0DyhkGnt8Qa2NuK6DmUz@mg5s3PbpgEwNuote4c/T/oGEB9k2h5qjVjx59kYjWhGKEE0m8m7tgb0wozooyklDhebh@g5jojuXcfwaJVx3JOIAWBkntGnDQRaW2/OkoYov0Ndtane0QX@EzQyxI8Rciszg1EFdeFdw4YGpEPdhKYPhYglu0t6oJAvCLKoimi6boz8oLY4lKmZ9oJK8PQBqgTUVQiQid6A29whW1fqDoBG9WdBokUVCZM@CjQVDTluoPULVPyItFLGX6zptegB4vRK7PxLhFlKwUt@TRpGtGGgfkRZxdhHhoI80tQHyBF95DlU6oY2546vZx/cFqN3h0ToRXFjahRgPpwoRU6YjvU4BLit64jEkYW46ksOCLrkcAtqzRuuwOxEibS6i66ipInAGm9DOnRsZwVWIGaEF0GWfWhZ0Mr4DHmHZkWVkTYXb6mMkG3PB6KwO4OedDRyXGgZjPVM6WADLbKF2hXo6Imox0iK5N5yBwsdRxy7fR/7QggwsjSoC9jEsKWCfqUBvwBWxnRo4HwOi3EhwbTVU1xB@s5oB8AqE/Sotm2giqa5U4YEsgedNEQ0JabrAjM8xa6C9URhlyLSego9g9btIn9FctB2fzVyEWv03rhjTq4q6jo6ih953Knmkh7q6C6IHtCIEvGeF09WqTsNueDFS87Il2hQ9uQBkAKJUOSJHqj90FU8AEbzbGrrCX6pifEZwo/9XolPggEDMkmNvAcKw9XUoRKBlWZ4Au2a2qqkD524IMBTQDeaEvSQRPTQXJA2oBGCrlkudzsauQDu4RJhsscUklAxUcRcFJdhd6O4AkJgWhbzK7IoPFenBmGhb8McIDjNOe0klgj4lpSgAXlwkKSgh0UHKvMxPyrdMMexTQf2SIIJJElyHonA0AEkaGJMEEFM3fTbgdBy924ovmzUalDZQKYCttlNLuq14aCnCJwagEUqkwSRiL7zzMe2kUhCfhF4xlIDwhPU1FqdnPsDF1octc84AAKycjbW5JCwQTk/MU/G3asFbaMjAvHY6kB0MnWfr3IgArDWULuJqvElqoLuG0eqYuXF8BT1tcpLXbFA@QDMNTwUgmtBUhZKOIEpCOrqShKxoIHbvELvTXUrEAmYCRo740YdSP5JMNYVMaJMIBOEjfZaS2VIsDkwPORw9/hhLWiLzFPqmHZlycFydM2izpsIzodhHx3cO9o9@vn2ChyW2alcdZDMXKmAXe14IvTtsZQT1crmIo454vvtm3FjwGUYngu8ieBMFkSlqQ6dyyQk59Ojz18lCUhCSA4aA5jxviLSMBgQuriO5g2udMKkn05DlFGQEJYIByTEGRkw6eivhek5HL9@jYV3NVGjwB1TZo01hiB0lA7sMJyInlcEsNCr02M9Ig0Lsqhp40TG3LQIGabnXZSdryaGCtQLVebdpw/2j2oUbTC6JlAQyfNBltLcrgh13hqDIr4KBtgfmHSSFucJR6mapnUlgXV9icDzsiVr8AMC1HhEhwjWMMyaN4C0713NG3UV9KgGUDvFcFWuXJSH9M@a0IV0YBeno@K7qhelHvPOKnJa2WNFvsvdlp7PG8VcebHb0udxdheR0nkD6AdCudEFrxNPQBdxLkUGYnWQ/GePriXco0IkqAJCmDLPIiKNy7M41F4Ek8Q9aQ/0NMcyxA8ox@MJn5SkeDh1IOoeVUEX4Pcnpp@Qk@ytJAEWYt/dPVDvh8DBwDUdz6BKA2rk2DO5PZwL1D2oI7ZjOX2HpCAMkw7DCEFsWpvN3b5jXyshDR0xqzGcTgT@i8M32gj6GvM1VR9pqEWllU1MarZ3BlxaKWSRSJRCFJVE4cWPtFMNyDXP97ODL@5DJ6LkZTkyy/QCEiyEoeRCk77gSh2IABGJQXpWZjCaf7zW2kMPYWECEDMdMLoo4O7ce6Uj5ZiitBJ@ZZLec65R/CNneqVqgQurWmBYINnBk8NHB0/2H@9@2PTVfH7JnpPLBSAcxNcBWUgcMLpha02xponZQnQxaBsuNi/gAmNQUMIJpbHnAuMWEURkCVhTa9jMbeI9Z2DHveTVzJyhr/CRrbMq9BgbHwMNAoKi3bVQGXHZzDb251h/Br4/8iqSBK18MO6IoLRKH@mOpfUlGg46BsuSFFRdDp7i6Ia3KgQkxpsaLAQb4gLRYUrHETVr6IDyQufHkTWQBENPx64ssz8AXRgn0Q03KUY1mOZG6oKGALqyFOWNMmBqA9oG77CceFa131HUEqvXiqzmJD4EW2r@ALvRM0B1SkBvBaRIXrGS5t3mXTIFLo2YriKJETFFBzk8gn2BRUCQpGOnqOeHxKHcAkdNkVdQGr0a45gucCkpL@eKSiEvgVoGahrIrAKOvAlDzdcHgu8IgE9wenTcYKEW9jxds3tiKjCEiQW57w5kNdt40WzaLRDQm3dp2nBqujFtNZRWskquB0kF8Mkq1N6l7GHdDR2g7lIjVE36Jmv4WVe7zs66Gm1dXSL5w1HQ5wgj8ngXBKnXDvDrrrHY9jCAtOgppZZgJQR@I60YELIwKIcPpJQEDQp6Wqh6EqZLAKEXxUOoOcC3FgKQ@WhGJDBN/QHwjyxJ7FFT8rqEi87ZgGssJwWHhsXRFFgeBUKmLWQxQaEHjXDEMGBS4qACocSD/nGWBDqQcOwCSx9BMbEBrT3oCECd83Ao0scuGOdsxmxsGJtkYMUBz13hi0QTXt8kXITQgPjy@z/oBXgisU0k9zSscUCFK5JdEFAkz5EFQF8@JT4daegaqMbj@ojntomKiMhRXwG6rvhmW/TdDcJDXJff/5PLT3778uufXH7yrctPfvXy0z@6/PQ/bAhvUMesb6WbTUHMNFqEj19L/J199c7uvTv3SjSFIE9C4v/vX/jVv/21X1pO@4p4f/Tx13708S/@zS998tc/@PhHH3/pxz/8@o9/@JUf//CrbxWv/X/9sqP/90@cIMozHBpZjDCID6IbDKAXfQhSWyN15@ycbGxsQPCNjW0oiY3tbZIm2/AU4LkB/eY2@GbguU0a4LtBWmTW4kCD9ciK0T6Rjp@LhqYP2sAtdSORTYrQ5Z1fTC7IYNCYiNDOT3g9xbdmdHaJ9gU448ISvYeF9owukcG0vwfdN7PNE78u6obUbMjNVvM80eymk82ZlFFaoGW3TXx4CTXZUERRADfkLQlJPC/NpChtEwoJQKI@cOcpoxN2bMUO6tKswj8wJ9ATAauEirQ4Jk9ZC53cwaHVLxqjwdRdBIjGq0A@xbHn@UIQXC@D/G@Rv7xm4RdFoSUdOZQYGRyIhTjshZLGaMr4IsdS2pSW1iGFPdap0Bs6via9L4K6IS50NPGNuCQI0IdQH4aJZvux6emgWmi24Yy9xTG6lUOHGDu4Hg/GwL73BuaIM/SBAzV9B3CSaJYEiYwTPgKbNgqDdXURbmzWyDJwigF6Y7pGx4TCp62XjmIoNOpTzTK70Vh2vjB6JUaxVWkYImNEZt92XEMAQkAIji5IouvduHo4m3tAR4qu8crAl3YByHdNw8@QB5ajUYo6NtSFhdqIcyHz8KDPQpAjo8tZNhF6IFqIrARcoyulODq36bgDYJeQG5yyUaMyGgYekuONuqI/gaBcAjuoRU@mDYGQdka6qqoW9HyvEvphXQBiD6BoUIuzQSUMvQQFPJNB0e6zYZRQp33y9P4@G2ugnRN2Rzju1B463THIYYGecWTY/QzZh1pk2s4QWKkdhn99Yh05js@0YrCsG8lgSqY5HFsaHSO5OoxxYzjd6TgWHTq5Kegcfux6mqWxQZvQd/f9xyAbPz9@VhMrC0CSdjq8MW4ct1sdLaPnweJMHZ2lDKdTPFYx@c08j91cuKISmUvgUUKPIa6ZBFkx0KKpNXIMAM8VeYawa9WNCE6hcExGmkd0rqjU/dTv9Zacs9T5REBeYs2dc9SZraNcUofczhwoz4BwUeUSzCKiAoWJ1lauhStSOLacAyrr3KNEPTS60lLAofsl3zL1nS@1ROkn4GDRhP3AsMIJuCNj6OAkE/SSFs5mgGiPgixbDGlAXzHCuQTKpnGGCroEDQJeFbSgiY0EBs3FNmiz6Zi2hBNF3KZEghHiKm04oHWzmT2PsVAHNGM6@LBVZzPCqHm4TOmR2Nj1ZhtQbNWr4eK0dWAYUzwegVGsNG0QgmaTToJfy2q0pMGjQ9IcDVLlPAmE7okqC81Jcb91EZc8SoYe4ZvNyR1Z/RBkElx2uHlX6htVuh5oDb2qoU@cMuygL@coFBve1QfAXUh6skxKKJ@x3XOsrsDmkqCuEaaFYAEFE/rRcshg1athuuFKSLoUlQVFrrqwiPIa3itFWr8OsLDsMkKE4gO5OMmcXpDGSYacit7IMn0QkVCeGASriuyrCzTpfJbmutrU44L1IDWye/Tu@w25xTBwQw3nh0qsFCfhOl/Q2lxnjCuzwYSrWnzTp70@nbU3Mb8g5EAAOpUAyQccLIIqiSIKckQlH@NinpeeAfpcwqDi0nSYIUZyJvYszfcNm9U5Nkm3ntxsNiWIpkaj3w6G5itEpvMXZg9SCX6QxCp5dnx//@hIRIEuEd/HeY4KNEcQHUEYWZfpkJKLma@QO904uYNhkqjcctDUQF1vB@GhUleh0o8NnM1BttM33AQ4JnGKQgdnOitEAzJpLCAQrk3SfUqjCFkClO1thqyyMv3P7RPbOYtKvAI1Pk0pCeRO3K2glJkUx7b5SvSge6GCJoAE@hT0ErXNBOVkm0oyWHw2xAlWEKqpgAg5aDQI6Ez8JgDzpNWqsplygAU/cEPq8jwtCrocvKaERV8DZxBkKIYgeO0NedGQhXIrvbkKFV2IFazkZvlfwIsYllF7xspoNxO0vV9ryCwNbMaMce/nHl3@uPw9Q4VsMgPPRmYpeLi4iDIduhZpeU3R8oolaGTISuiABWYkZAmxYJ19UGepP@X8oPViMOqQSJLziOgqkpxcXFAakk2VUBqCSSGsMGahVgyM6ZEDuXkUrLFflAloaw2WW2CbbXJ8qGgvz2eiDxPXpdMrMqlwyi@GYzKhaZ84dFYkMrVlUcmjHBiFHp5Y10Pigk36WAKN0sBg1XWp84adHn2sAKCTA8G0M3Wgw86BBAyioyYd0RcdgV4R8/JSi6Vog6WctKcFMxFe3QIplEsUuNfpmOtAgQi4hip8rwADJoX1WRVzohIu2jdtqPWWxYYiQGeZZ/3qKh2yRPdgzWnw/h8fd4H@10tnAB0Fjs9FhjZ03VhSQm9tYQVB0UIfqwuWDSOPLVOjhKGm21DqmgtZ0qzIsBo1naoWBOj@hzjwHpQ41E18gMB5QzVjKWfzZuF7dSSrpp5sYJn6Otgrq5ZYVHSSBNS5LiUCE4JMgwairIsVgjFhExUL6jSysdsTFS4tIrQys3IfjP0xe4LMe2shmiO8b2qbAaSc1zqKIbFV3jcUuaudjLuOMDrpR3JqYQXsPPd0FEkAcSCYNG2jcXX2WQbZqunwvQ5s3rVJZ/R1W63w7LE3EjpU9@4yG20IwxticC32XAdiBp/DRYb1VDMt@njLmhhgh4oSrBmQcF2msEA08wqZLa0zRRlk8NlrWTT/DhynpqfTcnbNBOxotD486ps0fLm8OvRE1Bk9Vo0MSGztZ6B40QwHq0FvKVXorsyhZglqd8G4lpmvmr6/BhrN/NEw@KEC/VrhxkqOHZI@tjR3brqhil8bbL42bB10F4em7oAYMCJKUVTUsMtY6CgoqwwXjs0jwCW39LGwOMBcRb7wkwshMq1u@o7u44LKNXXpLRgZW8iIy0UXKoforKOQ7pzhvVZsGIBKyp6re7LXK1P1FkxJsHRLg/57bTewNBSIQ423VNAz0zPoYzVhT1Ym1Netle7LVT8c5FsctLutOnum5XjkGX3eRKC@C1Rgz9UVeZGWpmYLdMB70XwD7wlXAMwLVLP6jlUo9SUNHmtLfez2kN8H77flbBFnUpRbOFMo9ji2ErzX8vMTyT25rYDoR30urv5cMN7Qta5iT8EMx/rcgUKAXzesztkDuURDihIbCFwTMa55OdOm4ftn6DLWkTbsMkZTKkaDVIcByiUw@C4TrX@W2HI3x9Z9O6Z0DW3xtkwsFO6JZUAnRZ/XipSosvIZQyiy/PYsqmeNjbGxUsF42vnIwK/Yb1Au3j5RcpCNzWBcHqcC8PONCOp1oBG@Vaqxf0bbjcxEw6m/20WYZaY2Aql7hCrzIRgO0XA9RN8ej5ZKdUkrs49uJtlgFDZpp7uUOvT5rHyodIuEtCSXewa9b9SUmGaHy6dqeVmWA8FlYX5lyXKTBpWNwn5ksudSxNRlHvMcFufU3AXj6jgoWRYX6K1lQeo6hZ4Cl8uSbdqGP8XnW3LTjuNYn6WkgKniR7UOaKkCXYh6U4ldE3eCTyzIfMjCw4GOTm/dYAXrbQKdEuiDyvJNhb44AfRWpSngFOcQp5@WravjwOFISxt2uhpJdM6c5ArRcykK/PoTB4LYulRrvSAZDIEoYkks3tjkmHjqdAxLY69JIXcTvrKYvRHfMscI5mVxHpfN3s7n2mNXONJoCpQyu6CaDIyhQa03iPZaFzeYCF5rgSYO3uu8J4ahS5N9Q18HMDKBKdj4XJouXpCUfMcGpcrHJXConFi4yDJwXU/Ex5prOo92n7y7tPbgeslXyMFQ6xtsu5SbuOZ80AJX@jDVbm5cPXxRIfewueoQbB75@hoCDezEmHrheyXCx1Mdink8vH3I7Qoj0HEc9C1a/rrFnte7W3vgDOyBMWArrCPburYC1dNn29vclHRIdX@Ai75Go6XF4Iv0tBwI9Rb0RDbJmKbj9FamaR8/FsVvnD4TXvZlevC6dQBP8xkrQcPaRjQwxtBHeY7vjAyB2taBWjjYw57r@Gk4x/2zjiLdqOsDRcL3z4r/Vj2zrzn@aERf7ZE19uiDBhXoN763yVA9tiiFLh903L742hl2xMBRDFas0Gnw1RynY/r6AD@yZjXb6DsdfWDeluhgYwcpHPZh1rfSY5EyJhHuo7NomUBedypifakt@j/D18G6Qg9GkFhHFxlukF1WjdLRz5iFkXaie2xEFE2kgoPCC62RfexcoZ@LV16NTX@OdGEVUzTEy6Ym0LAu7cHii7VSFv2aYM6Gg0UZa2spFdhROBcMGYQfZV20y@vaFppYNsseK3mG7ugnvXBYay0lgwU9dPDPXBiWBfelqrO0EmmlNmEPxn3vOi9ko/FdkMTwsX50gi7oXRiRhu5Is4PXOgqqloRf@sG7DaLV2LhxyiR/45wJhVMsQXNMeLXhBaUyXjtUZpkjjz2J0Fs70xYsUAKV@@p0IKPNdLXOHBRM1@ixGQ403SZvDh0XBPM@SBuCjhPlOECOfJqJFIwn2U4f@LVgkTlwCLtOP1y5gGh18UfdofDhE6Ov4WriR6aP6y5X1AraPlYtPLoV9xfGmmd@YQw5W1fZcPMCNsvoLi47RdsKfI@1vqk/XCqIKJEBgYNFm@y1VP3R6XpZnA1MDxcsRYYbxp@wyrFKjLWuDerBCsirw/LRvg3zBsS@BVwJvWro3BlN8ZOpKTXdNGpu@nQwNXiv0xDXLQ@7MRFn4@Fo7AWv1WmgS6IWB5uHjJ15ZyYgF14B1yQDzfJXD0gvjKyCgBX0d3Pj6igr5Ium5fTJF0syAXkM5CuUu1dUnHvQ8x7iehvXXlETadxvOauJ4xmCyzL2CsrWwJX9tunfPGjj@7j2JnxjZlin4JyBPPAIn@LOZ8UgHK@myKPbxfj597m3dN1Q8545Y1c30BhturEo8QexGnvhkmITtynATUPOFvUx3bGgeYHBWtlkdMce@4I7tm/sFQo39goV3HhpoRqQxBf2Hz9PLtYGuvD6NgEz3Jprblq7HuBKJTNtkLHW89Fl6FBNuM@2DDqi639vCbOL@xrplF3fd1apModT6EDeWhcC5j8e3jd0nBW8Ne4nzmPHdqA3GgGjHB4Z7MP3pXUcqwNisEf4aTfQp3trNM8o2jWdEJM2tJHRgfK15qa36YsY4vuar63piugQIFXtItOtdcW0Oob7ER3bWzCv01aXE/TQmFC1YX2FYW1Q8HWdSbs47LbURpYmZryR49jsSbmtDC/l8c1cBboC@nj7eXARV9cvqfwrVa/lrD49ZYtAjC7bmWFdXl2j41jsecOSI9tkU/6aaxqe9Ag/9KduhRwRQPrybuQhxRt5yFzrAUn2VPPoHPxqLWKOUpl8hhU@A83VHZzwCgw3LL5Z@Dr/FjYdLdhn6wI6QPgJcCxNHwf7Zt6WLGvYGdLHWoVhoTSPDIimiysDn01tX5tcL0w26BN8z7@wYCv6Cj5kV9ioCyRxCNpI8vZua1ERvEJVc0QflFOvnRWna3EE2zT01xoOiDmUXvMh6CV/yLP0hBrXDEkvNCM6WCxp9HPvlS1peWUaCDSWIfgDF9R5yb9pFDvca2TFtMd4aOBc8vJky1rR1fEGNLPO6mnziLm6hhBsewe8JNoCj8mHwu5ayRPRw//pvfck6ITbhVy4/wawrtsn6iHxY9cOXm9TAw8dz@@Zk6eQblzkv46dYLbyEARerGWgKbUuE1B69thiAwv9hWVVwy5VxwS6W7EgWJRd@4Zg2KcC3Q1tcj1HDvt@S9rFjWx9oysEmwHghILwKPyUKwIL3ivmSRd5I67lVCRG2EkhF6zuXEXcs5AzgLzl@MLIo29p5B0ePHp6LI48ZWX/tDvAjx@uyXFLuwuoJXlhtOkjzV2Y1mSrzbqm50v3ninC3qMDEQHW0JvNXQjwwgm4pdfaIc1wQ1NJW6sFoa/hrxYQHx4/fpSef/lIEnsD1xkayUXvvWfPMvghyXvPVnovhn4AraPnTNYGP9hXlOSK6ht8HruOe66IaR2mYwO0UaiMD9nmJLcKV7ozMrrH05HxPnSeyMG9t4y@sDaTT7RTs4@tkJTXEoo2VFIWC7nkwsJrULYNN3qvK88Tc4TcUqcvib3WrjpBySErudnV0sNNE/tXpRgiBwsOPlsgRb5eWxe31JU07x@bMEVR1tH5mdaDciX5tYW1DLBqGthyTt9ixtgIlBchchJ8qFWCeesy8aIwBNYt4QNH3gNHMHbWrna5CUHkXFjZ4M8Me6rZAp2mukm8qEBoXLt2I8gXjbeYa4oW8pzivt0rp@@iFfMkoVNj8paIj92FIHt79w5uC3AU0PJmqHefPCeHmoc7cdwMuJhi4y1SPJeMPhJw3Aq3gVs3gHPQdQGVeiO@/mh1e66QZ5rbdezp5Pb5NfphKXbtdKfUCBfaKJBhmRNzVV@ls3Gtw9WriW6Lm32j4UyX5ODFHVoCRJdf/lVFkWW6/w6@FZlZbymZsIGTBJq0KW7qtuh1fBCxBh3lFhEckiu10UfGBFedsNHgVUr9yv6tcEPfV0yu705u8ivd4Je7Ib5rfuhIsqKs3IAwf4MfyYuR9yPHOhs44p7mGt7KGf8VCbopI@UbMlJe4M7BxuF0zjAwrxfx8cuE4LWyth4bvpsbDZyOmbthvcry179rpzx8zaUrWvpO8GkHs6@O@GxsrKTaY@31ag/Kck5WegE3NAZj@unDde/lSdAOCL@G3TfZboPknuPvU9sNGlr0UfTq9Qbm6P54tD7FwCTxmIarfH0J8ANQnp0zj9zDT@Dm8vqKQQBcD7fafZ1wS6IRQtx08@HxbljNnj6T1IUY56n48HDJGT8S9Z8@W3BzjclknfYrTNYpkyt95rE@Oc4tRbtVf3G6gljrvysCuQMYc/ReKxAxrvfes@u8AfW4gT@0Qp/3NHs@dLpUYF3Hp18UrvQ8nE7ossmVJT1gq9ZW@bn6bUvGoGc2TYjbk9pt3Bmo3V5XK4@ND@kkBMhDxGfyCUMabMBlTHKDMIU0yNqG6pzMpaCl5D4bDUx7stJruC4MXTWa@Mhb3Qx2yTPLOSOhMryePairkWunxirKrv0oUShnbxbHsldkq3Xlwk70CF7riuTeOontCs/ARQ83cRMMf6RLD0LL@2ryVvj3noXgt8PuWQ4O5HfN8fB2YIo2nb4d0L2B/V1FaN4OhgdgnAwc174dNKxOlco94y0TsfHWkMOp7rxFGjq93u1A@55zO9DjseWbqLysBn3ijC3cKWCV377bX@le36o3m2JFXOeJe4t7Aze53h/4/tAZe6AMmRHzjAIKH5n@kmNYZxbdcKtzwxZtJ3kF73sO@Txuar6CFK/fsozee7AObnnmZoxz/fTL37lx3Vego2n21kb@2uxTy9s0Otsc3gg7333uwHVsZkuu6x7nO9GtiOmhZpm3MrRw5YN6yxoI7NCYPznN3s61QEB4sL7M3p9O5nrncu4ttrnEKr89FYjS1/VkeCoPLkVXsgujf2yN2ZpVvPPe/wv7Q033kovrwRZ2tQnnk7118sDigMJyt/7syb3d4w8OH630/bw27Kzm9@EBFup9tmy0t7B2@Jp4G4260gM/pGf4FLyBBqIVHXAVcLeLKxP0H@w@Olzdsw9Av4VSxR06F0ap5x1zout62rCcW12Oj8OPSu8Du0Lzuo7k4dRwhPEasjHBbdVo4toPv67uBXgz9MIOftfqwhPDfzZ2e8m1OxWsWDPGtqIACWfxsA8vE2w6x7ZuYRtmeGJ4IksiYQMjTC4fgre4@wduiZ/YxC2hN@lOHwB7cUE2gt01wIMP9@sI9hPBnWNNe2zghiDsaCy/tgnR1GpKvky28dS5ClFkGieeyVlmG3SGkTXI5nmwV0aloszIRo3wFZ4Eu5VE@@2zPeMBMe52DZkiwolCNn3w2Qx32iD0ECRyQegMgqDjpsJgE6XFPYeqwV4kkKbN88ODw/1nx7vHz5815NYs2KskzIVtQ2zhjkh3sl0eMh/QzSYjdoIE3SPHgujoyTc48@CF@SJ46Nty1mpLWZtnit/GMJvnti1JdLsWSZhB@gSexUZ9UawGJ4Y7zDEtoGCnngrbOYVuAANlxFDzNE4otAqRV0U80jwPshX4Xz0jkfriAZsVPGITIw42/YfW03ecbhCjZ5DbrzDGB7sHj54f7ZMwgfNac2Z2/UGtnGdnQgTbQfK4eYtF9zWKB0HiUFa1WvxBHAgTF@OkQjfYoecx4NaR8ag@4NY8QegUSWxS/EDBeFQo0v/4WJrFRfwkKwmw8TBRcYgW6jytKLh55jFUEnL/6OD9/SOC6d@/T52RRIiCHOPuHn/xvS470Sjccy88XNQdBpowlJbnmN0KbrmjGySWU9Rg364uwf0m2a40xJjQ04FozaPDhAvHjSbpPmjc4j5B4eY58/19sOQoB1gMyU4eovvmREceRSe3cRzd1xPq@xndlvbKjq1JuisiO0qV7aUcoaZVLzw9BZcTgOZO@2bTM3HXHiyHnjN2rzQS3CqDblAskl08dxVPd9Xo4VyQ2LHtsw0eg03fYlBDxYhXZcgmTSw7yotfAIxvbUAj6Rh90yaebYJ451fIR1CDccq@wnZ1EoR6/FqQEHWFmgRUyBcA2VDCEI/IIMJoH3fqbLrS5a/8ktSvEjD7YP5qYJ7I98D2tcDWA/PXmfmFhBVUil87wSlKy2KCcAfnIAcsIVzP/OlP8ShmPrGpKCdt9zQdz8tVeCjVPMmTO5tNQdhsyLWdTQ0I6b@aNKE5S6ncqXF/0Ose9KUmz4Msl5Ok1Pn5efxB6tB8kScFoWuqhVeT6SxbyL6azLJK6dXJSCk0xFeTFl@qZU5azUaLHB5@@Kb9JslPTqevoN9JQAXbe8orOT5WKZPz7UI2dlLG0xshhyfkNVwnPYJ/an7dXTBraO70oN7GeRJrNvHcZL7IA9uLt@BPOcVLuBjPaNTFurjdevMm2dA0fwJCi2mOvG4XbmdAEqqafEagqd2FRsQCSKRJ35SIcOWHkx6Z7Br9/nhfm5rjB/6OWBRLorrAmLYef/GD4Kp@8Pw5Ic/J8@evj9awsVY6nRCEBjVPQsdHILdkJqTS1vIxPH/xL36wMcucH7a3/uKToWRs4Ospvr46e4zmZ0r@zsbGnXv3crmMqqrMfPjFw5/f3d3N3c/kDxv57Zwgb2z9@Z9tbKjqlipttDxPacUbJycf8qqc48W/@G68fXj4Bc@rZ//7x2/qCj6K8DglRVLGK0sUMOKzBLdC8nnytlfsdUyBKzalv3YsdD/fIEp9u/g/v/n0VcyP1VXpAxfefuxVrFCKMSMYwJYNbaexemwLwQqz2FSq1WpgLP7P/wjh6@8BHvSZbsGjng9xFaaxulCjQS5i9QIYFFWFeP@fjz9eSCHwM2AlNdoiw2sHGGKjweeKKr/dgitFry0ONzsTZEkK4Wx/4BsOUUp3lbtoMcECLxteOPbWjOEJtE93iPjiKA19Qlp8v74h3d8S4BJHkqKoTUW5C@xXuJOq1QToV2izzWbzd3Ej2iTtDfuO7xDj7gdLV@yDf5JrJZrqB/@U1xHZM3XDdTJcrLCx8/J@vQ75zdazqXqaXkEjo@2tWOIdZwd4zfFg7JoOHmVbfYSHMtV5uaTymUxm56gNQchkgiQUJhOxjSig3WIvGWOX2CbMBZtz4MjqIlx15AQtErmzUKF1DkdexhvQRlov18PF9vH6y//8l9/@y2/S37fp/V9xpzi7a/akFACdQnOpw7VTqej1Ol93@fMm2utQx@RKqVKS2rNmItWot45ArH33Ip7Pxskza5ppY7MhzWSzQcPXabT1IHq012Nz5zpzqS@6BR4MmDrAO6AUiYX5XMhXRDVCrsBxsXDRndA4rbcEHLutCQ2lkG8JLFRjBwqHV4tlvt2KCZtT4ERqq67m1adkp84uMtj0iIOpyaqFMCNBeuvzvM195rb6olOsHgarz2E@K1yQpjIXazSklkH7inqY0J2NykapUqioUru@/qrOQ@BFQQ3DOPRip7HoqpKgHob0jEU1c8HtxWJJRMVCwgpMlsLeAgdlBUxjMgn@ay5aXNmCwlcDk9rmSRXqh5oV1H6blxVobTvtSHjfhmsDfvQPV2TF5wZ1CZwpyPVrg1SUlJqV8ncK@yp2vVcvV2jU05QzCq16WkQOKYhXYDjoS4je6XRe6x2QTDSto@ma4mtjbaJNNb8z7kw6vj7W8YRycojiXTsgg5t18k7JCakiCrFsXtmM3cW8ZdUyHvYNukmplC2r2aKSLRayRVkt5bOlcraYyxaLgDBbVLPlck5Vs4VitlDKFgrZQhkPVAeYAsBkEUMxny1nudibxgY5YvxtQtLh1Uzfej0XKUfDixocvAXBmcRAcAKtP8PF/hmuuqIqJAWdowwPkAipkaj0Bznc08yxl@FIDIS989abVONNiiyWlhCkGV5ie6eVFmazBpir1eC/VY@MVXoxE2S1NUunt17UQQZ6UW@kAeWLAKUoEIpUbNdJa4t6RbEF0QX@Wy0Qo4T0VmOr5uzRW6RNUWgByq2lZO7s0Hq1AyHrm9Dkk@n0piBsNABPI@iNABhrX5AfwNRKgKxyfv4z3iSec@IFZ2drC9jKbGtWnzW2ZrOtLfhv0ecseIPrbOvan77m1xqYuX8LWVKzIdWbUjNgSy2wi1IdXUSpCYY6vAGukVVLLewIUdARW/8y/2Jm/oxcMMktEVLNxVIkFcON0rKxFBd7efnp/4Z38/LT76PQSuBnVLjYOSFcTEqVCXWjrzJIbo9t8phdNpjxDq3ogg71x@hos4eNqrAkvRRJRaD6cEIpFZIi9vRtp9fG761F8hJAAWy/b0B7Cdks4dVSgW@nlalKYlt8oUg5689du@Lx@L96qZaLcaZu4wfDLz3Pe7yQynk6AbiqyoqgXNTZvtjs4IKfW3X9q59bd3GxizJBGiUIowsXg2oUkyRQE7lYfWuIq07x0B8BT288rX0oPN8V9pzhSPOpPo6DdSAV1A72a@VyHfUkY/OQNp3U/RQ8Ffjvb0AmSLMHoM1eTR@CDN7sZfNqE9XSdzVQz4GnCZ1X@Hv0Gn/kWMff0Sv8kePX@Dvy8Uced/B3/Ap/ux38HQ/xd@8V/h6/xt/zPv6an8tmlSq/eU7Jk1bKymxzwlMyVaE7qzc/57vTinGqWQle3VZB5kxWWblmc@VkrPk5NnBSCc6xwZXAhu5XtVq52qmpAWiwjAl9RNMLjwZNsG/KKypJ4oBFtpx3XAGn2uEBDulsWXHc@E@@8ckn8VotLsTpOQ45cBM6CNShQGCFkDmWEjzMDdIHhe558epO/HMNOjiVL7ca6NkCDy5WI5vKpiJbsi4rHaUDBpPILpEH8kDpKlRvkw0iT@UpkYeO0gWTAT8ZTKbcI3KfyLZsAxj4gslvyz6aevDqw68HiFz4mbicq6PIOoGILBRS6flqShtDyhdt8u7A8fzMqMk1SJzwLw1QwEVFlMWC2cLTNhr8y5dNKdVSyyUiYiUX242XzXiLb/K4F7NazpHO1NhovuRBKpF51hjQhcQ8D7T6akxqNiVWAEA2WqKzWbu9/@R@uy1h99gkRj29kwZ2v7NTA/YfvLZj9ep2s0J7j7AHiUlb2816VkBzIQ19gwpu5KFhGXZGSn/Ga44Y3vUNSoDWy7OXoAQlzlAVOjuF11lo@KAJjzZTkqi3dPZBc8FKDXAhrCR9sALDkgFSbbugNpC57Ad/0Cb/uf7mv6z/4@ckSRKNVjJxPttK0CuJv2TyfHY@C571ZCIRWBJb8EMHsGOQ81kdjRToHEyNRLKVnM2YGzwTyS2GsA7RbNVp2DkcdDKxKEoaLXsk/mnfEHVwNeNV8pLf2nL1i2aVcoOcXCYx/mWVaPOZhmZzIstJ4FjBRvGCTTa1Czosm6zqeArjZqehtP78u/QwgO0kBcrnqlUlRZhFzanVai60FUvVaim0bCYS5etXXd5WCqA75XLJZLUKlu0QrQxWCNsgb9KkRprwbN29yyIpqRcXIc5srpCWcYanWg1jykO0hqfpjH2DHHrwlG6kD9wiHyPIFEgwSJ2Q6UkcyNbjfIW/ezcRnLW8vZu8e1ctyxcXkctoBE7KklO73TXddhvdsxcXfJunswPlPNjl0sWFIpfTSpwkHTfxBA/MhbgSgkLuqHUabRl4tporgneQgvzWViFXrxdy4FIoQUDIFOPYVRLn41U@dk6zoZSKjI/xVXQmMWjQ0Gt657MYLUmSyycTwAOTIFXOYvhzkV2y7iqfT1Zzshw7n/EMWCmXGXSS5AqJUroc/GobSVIHkYn9UO7LpnOpYmoHJGj8eZNVF3LU6rlRU2a1c6OCxzDNqnpwHCl@qG7cvZstA2lKcozcH@N2GZkmF7DjGnRMKH3Bo8nF42ly5y6HX/G78Up1h5asUsqTWLzKHIU4sHVSAhpLaiqvlJAmnNnD7SdAhOAUqotukA1OpW98cGWmoW6gI@i@i7yP/rkuXKRLOqSPF@mj7klMYtGLWIT506euR0AOuwLfyErD4hW5GNHFhtyz@SyrpXHyaKybOOx1@Gh3b/84o24JJKY@2N3LqM@e34spaM3P7dQ7i/aj/d37T59DgMNH@7vP9t89eH//@SG4e@RsfkW9RNhXRH3GgmmF/Yx8wH3kvtYMQzPGhtE@G4/PXpGPTLNtQtFaY8ib03eJZ7QhSyNtnr0q3LrpaR99pLkjepHL73z58ju/cPl737j8vS9f/t63f/Lpt78M9/fg/gZ7f@OPynl8/uTTX/2Dy9/9PXD8r3D/Kdw/@Mmnv/Exu6n9h3D/twW3Hwb3Ahy7OcD1tZ98@s3v/uTTr/8m3L8T3L95/f6VH6y@v/2l9TeG@@Yf3Azzjf8I9x8yXCHsN36XueH7GvzvMriv/@blr/8n9v/z4IfG37v89R/iI7D88m/@@X@7/OS/qGrpz//95Ze@efmlTy6/9NXLL/1r9fI3/r0iLz7@4PLbf/zXf/KHf/0n/4b@v0eff/g2/8vf/OW/@t//6v/4qz8J7h/A/Z/A9IO/@i/QXP/uj7@D/2/@8d/96Xfw/7/@/t/98bf@7mv/jhp@ixn@4Xf@iD1/9MmXf/SlX/vRJ5@ueX75xuenb@H@6T@Dy9un823wvE2@PqvLpz9Tev4x1JjHAnUAau4vXv7GV6Dy/johl1/@Hn7MAfea//dUhcJ8j9n@f2BQr@cZfWQwwf2tyy9/A0n0vwCJ4B/R66uRZcmHWb46twBZf3tFoF/8yae/9l1qixmVOp1ywl66pJbSKVBoUuVy0FMHs1EQ5CvL2CIEQUxfRe6z5PdV5FuX3/n48rv/@vI7v3X5na9h/yzkypndjKDcMpUHgPm3gEPAwtvAIeCHEH87TUfohPSHYNv4MF/K2rZd/fDDD7n2hYRfDe1ckA/hRz4ML8K88KuiwCv0Q3f8zIiAe@PlyxbO/y64SQpDLqnsHXjhyh6ISVDvpLclRWVexoW0yUKRKjhkS9nmQtKlXi9VgR@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@YUWrI3a1MgMnAocQtA4a6nPfGFikWqbm5tcrM5n@ad0NjgtScQ9qdAVbtCeqeZUIXyhzKOzQZf7MSo@xsXpGY6aq5hNcvnxd2M5uRjjNuP0NGvCIiJ30uze2UmRO0BW@l5wm9CFZEI66@ScGCPjVjrNqxBp3QFbipIwTbFxL0ishn9wj9HqRmLkUHNNL8NlKKPMwEusxdCbPH36NEgvdXhR49LQDtWsgnacCRyPxxDc6OKseyYjihkxkwneIn1TBzEwiNQ3eIubSHqyqOEpxRIeY2vrA6QL9@bNG6gbHNKicgAqNzOSmporUU9Cq8EEl3hpwwzHNpewrGm4klTNlTk2PkGUQo6QBK0RcCUJLplMQB1PcmzdFate4ZWIqyVQohESSkxMABhDU1CQU7G1qfQTI5IvLlkhZYtWHHVkI924HCBaFMrSlyjlk6Hn3lOy9/Tx4/0nx6NWi3AGPTbZaI9cRzc8L4F@u0/us@qrlgvJWKOBeT@uqMg5uf2KjNU4fXD/6OBZhTCKBUWXoPmo0pn0gC5lhYuNRh9sxVwcbXcNHk8Dc/hn@KzMSZFQy8DVk7E6F9MNVMOgnuIf7io5MvpYfR97/XvOhCTkDM9nlAIqyUmcGIbk/LwzJrinJdsAA7gDrt8TIb@Y8vq5sDDfhA51cqRyzCAo1ECy5VJoKDKDUiwgwFN2nF6Wqz/bPwbMx0@JosoiOXI6JiSq/iGZiIQADzhyhoaTEWY0NHKkY3PoIIRVswy77w828YhivinzCwTabMgZ/KnZLDyVXCGj5IutjQ3rXEA8TVplznF14gys5wLS5B24CPcOR94BJ7iEGeGcEX5lxYb1D55WWeXFT4dJAlL/zHd5JQ98IcnhDEWAjxstXlUgOrSz5ak@LrbxxS/6pF7ff3JfOHiAQxGTAQmXNgpmVxyItOJ0x65BffuEdM33TVyOLXZNb2RpU2jEQK9UHQji45RrbDab9QDnwQOi1lVqZWG7@Jzp1KUD5tlE4wgw6B4XuxuOvnDFu5VK7Y2SK0LaKpU3WVXlwIFLgaxh9jagttFlKimJ/Xi7llPktBLObZAkz/NVDxKVzZakFBdTeB5e2WyWow2IcBWDI3Tx0hu5VhMCHp9T6NolDg8x0CY1NboC2MmdOWxWZrDoAx6k77tEDv2KzC@whd0CZAVX89KzcqsBR5Hv3s3iGFQ2J0d5J5Q0ZAZFupnNZbGQwA1cW7FcMZg0g/y1Ypxl@KRbA3OsiRlmjVmJ8QRtyP@yJZmLNWLQtLlGq1H7//7XanCtyb/cP5Cl0ahxE@CQi3fgjDD0TZZ@HPfYeTr/P306XLTe@B8@dR4/dYYO/KEnfIwMvDr/V6tL1pv/AedE5lkFAZnzjQlUJ/jl5DxY/@HbH//9r//nv/@3XxXxCmyRwz98@1vM/Xd@FZ/f@vbff@sX/v5b/5a6/Mrf/86/Cbz@4Xd@n9yHNj59rUH/yV1@/ZPLT//o8vs/uPzkty@//ydoXfx/@h8Cr0@@NXcEM7pc@X@L/M2v/J9/@9tf/esffPy33/rB3/7WH//o46@rJeVHH//S3/7WD/76T79GwP7jH37lRx9/7W9@6ZMfffyLALf4//EPvxp6fSlyBDO4XP@DO@Dl/sVcyOlwWp/OVG8FW4jW6aryhlLOtfaBWTRIayvcXbQO0FvsYyiC27rUeCxqyTeZG1/3DKsn4lrtGr81qmdlld8Ktiivk/cNG5lxEL7erXUdnR7QXu2Kpm0bLn54w8LlcnzVsXFjwFo4HQw9dvK8Xzuj34lXjVpfxK1mXFuzIHjH6U5Fz5@CqKU7luPW4qCMxkFafd90LFpfwLzbdWyUBO2aAcoKDsFvZ7O5CuRPHDmjbTVfFIjQUGQQ3/BWSpkudCjuNvRjFTWzYWwXi5WuqFuG5m7nK3n01qNJ/O28XOmLHz5@9ND3R0cgeRiev50rQwDcrg03VtouVfJ5aMM8n27QGFt48jTrqIWNDejYDK0rwBvn@D1BLbUqNP5aLR7fziqqoFSycokLMjsnmF21hZxS2JYr/iIZyb5l2o6b4Tk8IDcqBSzAgVLPybktCd6ggEu44ADEkjrZNfoGyg@05JQtaYR1AowAqoGxA8b8ltQBownG8pZkgnFczyryljQGo17PKeCqs1qCpUHMbg3ixJylMdkZrC6ZgXIedNQV27GNGVfJaBnznJZcpdfrzVLn6bmF084FZoMynQlapnMeWavCAlyFjDOCOfcEF60HVeQ8WF9R4dV8ia82qnN7scBXWzNuZ2h0TQ0PN2/K59dDFUCAYlhjEFGTcLOK6zh@pWP0HNeYA2aVQgjIEnQdIMfPouiaMsZ4fj26wgLQ5HxOvYhqHcvRT4KY6Gmeq@LK5fkZpwfkcI3ujEWUqWRCRxaUVg4sLCy22IsXXCx19H62XofaeZ4rqrl8Lq9mC4V8UQVhsZwr5EtQOeSCnFdVYBG5cqlcnEHblKQ3MXoAINk7D9tshR57kNAqbHPPRosk3zwxrfNSVmBMJpGsgnQRe8PF7hy9r9br68e4EiB4v68K9Vo2XwZTFk1qlsoiqiqoWSGrCEoW/7cYVPy/PbwKfxWfECqrcse45c8TkHlB3LfJI9wxxHfIsePQr4LuGfoaiL2BRrcX2nMdz/tHwNzT7BPmdd9k@@xGXg81PCjPG5r@YA3E89EQdwsy3H82DPvDDiQQeToDuAcP13KcVQBF8vwQHkcH7z48jt6rc/042ukeiMO2uocQx/u7ew@5Arn39Mn9K698gC5PHu0/OI6sReYbBs1HKH5@/9Gjq9bglXv6/Kg3dly8uQdPn@fmj8gJP6bicnAtA0XOFEnwQCuKTCjZkw1QsUODwuF3XHdzZXI3MOYLc6OMxg/Yl2KmF33qxT42rHDH4edjGkFG3zGIzjaFwhFJumFjMAqgFMscNyK2c0aKMuk6lqW5xOn1NsBxoHmkYxio1FoW1kSM@sxxre6Z2TU2QNSEOMoKnqyOieAeApLhWKfbDIBSgdv/Qt9sE5zT71hjg4xHZK0jvNAJja7ZH4A8ceaEAFxH0wjcn/WC8Mbi5d/s4LM4qNs1H@s6OBfjdp/iaEU5xvN7PP9Q87WqaxRfkPr@BGomtBvNnWZKmSzv5/k@zgBbnt9tpMagIW1s5EpEbcp7Ml0gNdVqilTt1IhSuKhv55wd1J9QIU@1jVipX6t4@YKyjT1xTU7vxBzvoVGq8rxmZ4BxZioejkU8cNxuhezbJvCNF2QitnFUtVm1cTyD0EpW@Zvf/t6P/@xbKOeR@46ra7j@GDVXQvXQQIEV6biJWi7lS@WsWsqUyqVcXink8xlFzSjFUrEM6ZKVklIo5ctKppQrg4CWK4NvvlwM1F9JSpFdC4e7MkzFlVIVQG/reI74Fh2CEQd1LsaWiJDXCS1JYlpkHxPegDA82bX7hgU4cOTMpx8vpswadNxEkUm2SACzRnQSe/BgT37wgOfvoQUXzu3JPN9FS74ky8V7PG9Qn70SyqC8w8KUcOtG3mcWWb4HZThmCPDUA54foGW/gBMiPG@iZW/3wQOMp4cWFcMD2AnzYRYrtBQBzEYL6OMUwasIG4DtsnhyNKH7aMEo0ecB89kDP55/N0wO@hwxMIbgYZjT3V2eP2CW3V302aPZzrOEfh4tu/TieRcs0MB4vg@GvgtNm@c7YMRmxvM6mPSpBm54djtujG/7Gs9PGXmQQDw/odCafsLz7dAdo3k/SE0eqVuhFoXleodayvjjeTVMNIJlI0uW53ORJQd5e/jwfW3gd40@u6Yue@uQ04cPs5o5Ge8/6Lz7bqff77jT3f13j9Brb@8hiDTTsdvpd4KAnTZcDoTae6hqJ8Pp1QtyfdBuVzRrpdfn2@2cZl/xak/bBqYQQr2ClAVXHyMatvfAa@9he0dbteSHImwjhxnCu4PXvSG872kd5hVe1Iu@J50OX4VmAOpKM8GhhoWrdrB5ngDHtjNDTXedKtonNSLTtdHTRkFuVakHGYKKJFdn6N9L4FPD0enk@bQxqcmt2qRWDJbc9hJ8c6LmTT6zMdxWyvnKhratqLn0pILfXTu9OIkLyjZJKHdTr0niSXJbBUVpg29ubwt8Q2ltF4ovkKlV8LGtKqVKTlZJklmzxQqEkeMyIfhINoqt7WK@Mg9cLKY1Sa0UiyD8AX18ECE6OB7cJonEmaGdJJOYdDqgCPmhGSdTmmmz2ktMMpMaSySZJquTmlJlu0MT@Qq2RKKLRxGMddwzgjCkfUA4AU0Jl4sleKVc4iENkpRIAjOazWaMOOc5uTQ7P/fOz5uziFVKYJoP6X7wheOT4@MPgVuBTDLNUDG0HgyGHroG8rxqYH334Z548DS04SkD4gMUjx1X3EMet@TD5OTQ6RiUJfEhdOygKIduEMZ3HUvcp@uqQcYOPcJdOcRgx1/x@OESnmcD54zFDIG8Kt02Er94x0MYzC7RanUwaV2SoKkiWvKMihTter3Wrg2N4cifQhbDUJ8n9ISCOZoDj6WdHiKDO/DR4Oc91xkGHu2aPIMObxKbCALZBQlv7GYAY7tGBOXl0Om@VNN6tYunMNyr3UM01Ta8O6DqG67ruDxoqny1t23Xxran9YxDw8XP@A@eboKog7tgJHrESG6S5j5C76FmNRPqLrHnaXwyHiY0od5JLjvhBELkgGRKfCHM/jkOoEPKeX5W7dVI4gWAvgK7u0kSXfFecjtXBYrdI@0kOMkvey97RCWFXJUqQgnEBU2QUgopoCVr9c@DhMZQn5BKBVITFPkJYMXIADGUBvXRkiNzVtVrFkkIZJKkNMpV@7UGBr/Ax5YAgoUgNC5aOP7/AWoHr8bQedahuVenMa3mjTv0HB8idxRVLlQn4KYUc9UBlLf2YlJ1a6Oxa1QtsAYzBoTmWKsCbYGEgOb1ReLyKx8nt4R8jblVKaoLlFfaYrs2qdq4MyjUlFq2Bh7pRk7O5EsgyuSLGRAh1EJGKWSymVxGKKIryA@ZfAYcQREDoShhJXhC@Iw8kUUloxhKJiG/NLsvk5mThAx0oMRLZnxn3x4PCbpAkWFtpXZ4a8m0mgISdR2ibQm08gKTqWK@gPYDMjIzA4rpyNAsFiApkGwqYW0mEGjzeDzab7Qqlf3J6AvglRBebRfSRTn9OpmsJjaSNc94RWdX7plQQTQgLnImmv3RBtTpYFaFeONhA0odTEpRrTQaHcxrUc5k5Sxk02xf9Lf4Ot/KyBsFBcpsRkfRFcI4y@JEAkhO3Nxt1EZNwTKgDJWyWuVEHL@PkXvumM5sZEuqUJbyqbzMZhMYCm4UsEikLUk0@eCjjHgiHi@q8fhcrU7Gqzhtu8HP59Gosk0X1CbiwLJJ/K6aL2zzIADyFb6s8gA257iYSiKHKU@RPc3wNBdnXDgcrCA5UNbPudn5bKvOTURuf2happYhtqnjgXimfiJyKMVmSMfsk57mY1sWuV3I7UFF5J6BpmdQU2MfDzMgLDzdwAKDtQKEFTob5Q@mAwPUIZGb0sk5X7zuCqVE8B1GtQxBPsc9w/0PttQX@Cu@eLz7FH8PdmL4FQTZ@Rz4lcG99OLx86fPnz6g37jPP0L9LNcORyT6qQPI7dVYlY6i4zoGiIbJ9W9/7eBsNZE28DNukhYFsU43CNhhsTSDrWqkDUI@67cY6a36C/Zu4pd9gJqjO6k3SIuukTZMVNTJ@xoIlNskDkWuucOGqmZbDbUIYgl0XQ2ZgaqqUoVUtGP0m9Q61O/JOSR6K13HbQA@T6ZTLS2EWb9L6v30pqxOY6dtvlDO0m/W23VFPiEb8bspPF5dILHTk426mkrHDyvZdPx@PJuLnSaam/W0Mo1LJJVWpz1c8YUrh6Q4wKlG6k42FX@erpT6mYqSxqcKz0qcCBuxnXZmJ1n2OFqTSWyJwBvl3dpu/2g3mOQgu3v1kjoNti@IvWjzpWKQxOYmkExNv9hZCl8HWegFTnVeKTfyM1w7uAQ8Xo3HzuMkFp/FZ414i4vt0I0WVLbRAolFWy3guq1glUA2VyDJGEkGtmI55iWSdNVEME3/ufhOLI6z4cTz3kClpmVBm3b42frnX6rAaGK2Ezo4Yx9HdEGUyudxrjcmvRx5X1RL2ccHT@377gODizU3LjYcnMcnVZ6h5Mkb@70vEDKCEouTZi02qeWC2VKlXheULRU3qCqSCggBPaUgyBd1xs3q1KOggs/lV34zN9kqgV2VFbCraj6t1utKCsTQ2Ojy0@/77pSc77@/@4jEce71x3/2XbX44z/7fbqoPD6j87FqthgDSDQqhWLs/Hx0fg5C4Iz55WOt2LWFdi0gk6Ro5WJKhLoglTQwtKUYIymIy0UlGfOEWPBJQSEvJBKKpCZT2ZKcBJ@LYBOghCqXwBouiqBOfCHPJ2P7R2ZeVXa2tiFn29mcWt2AYlWi/TNI9NsyvHKMi5Uev7wgBCx6vdvvmyo1SVLQjt4IZOuNsAVvKOE3wgZ5WavjakEFt94Ip9hT@AE/LniJ19NSKk5A1yb1xqw6a6XpND0d@3iRsptXiNHcwM9Al51SNvyMlEd/hkGt1MEDa2gzUh95fCKVlKRul/Y7uERCEOox1uraBsnXob6kJEhlKpxWZz9BaCYvv/Ibqlr48Z/9ykX7ov2hqqrlcrmgqLGf/nRrbI89o1v/KQQ8DLdbg0qkm12srMfOiWF7YjTmQDs708ZDzkw7GqsgbKM3MwgVGUSd52JjG/UxBh@OXOAYBQGZ1OzbRpeOWHCnKFHTYm2zDc66CQqWIqCQZKg@R3dUSlY5LtR1mL7m9vUMxUFSuLtxo5Xkzrl30AvkMwI6X5V7Z44KHIYgkTl627PG7oh@Ppug4ZRWhtyFIBDDO7h53AZAJ0nQbwvAiaGvvhaUJdmjVKMyN8GtvnErOhBHuHcgSLAXvDUlI831DApp2iAriAhC00k9ug2IuwVxWyxAm7omaO4ZQIaw1LFANqhx3DsgX1IqmCB2EnMLAKrAU94BAkAeEgFis0W2SDZJzs10ujrf526G@5vgh6RauBEbh8EQWxfIFAWuIhw4gfqIBwtjvQhKGPjegmOIhOFgK95qoIBicGpDgd6E6jB5a1SA62yAJUSzRu7enaeqVjO7SUJzhPhPzBGO2NJysFenFZCFmvwdYKkgUqXTWNjvLFc7oHiaJhdqncC2DqwuBCU8WmccB/@3rrRYI68UFfWoYgaC8mKtQgeSQWAkOytDnWzViKIWkyRKvA5p12mi6DY90fBEc3JHVD8MPWeQwp/GwrO9gFkdL46CB/X2vmFdDC8ignsElLAx3bLSH2iMGXQNyxziUjocs0amd@CHoaNQkBXTotA90wVVmC6sC/evS2SVJAab7/dH00E/mlNzBD9dyyfxRUMhNIG3hvupBfFsUPFVd6BAvZFj0w3YfGRN@PEg1AjgURDBE8c3WLLH9hkexBeUDQ28mCLIJWg6WPMxxXRDOcc2PBYWV6h1XEM7CWmTIUZfJPqwS9QySdCKZuNiDTtCl6SBaII7oEEhjTuWMYQkPTMM@hW7V5GkPgh@4w7Of0uPTahXgwcmdD@2J91nBJbOzBNTOsaNsAWnhx@7U@SABWRFbH5sjRsom2OrSyzHOSGWeWKwyY3E4mZ2eAZIIQPKTwYoO7@BsBUUe9VsBgfClAyDgrsIryIzljILYTcS0@T1d1bZSLSxRC9oD2ZCqVjGqWYv0JdeF1wwmOJNPY7u3VcjqDwkwC5GLBdaJtsGK477YMWTItC@m0hytHw9CIIhRZw0GyX4GJ8UvZFl@tTIjVzjlOBgCId9DDBNvR0kAVsx5PYd2gHQtgctC/fT890KlFwaUuJ2Ezo0vYDB2@QOyaocAkLMCMoSADiw6GvL2MEPgmI@PL8LBSPSmSLkK9A6h13ww/26guqH4cPajWa6u@G8epONAB12OjSuGmHNIrTkFyzYOrA@06xvgGcBUrgiJRsJPg1o03ySZ6ij8FeDs9rOUV5SIdcxZQhiCEgNWKiooCHLodvqzk/MwwUj9zSPHauCtR4q/dnZmUi3jhy7pmh4eIqc59iaJY36JojDjuQbw1FwXrepS6MQ79wksMMjxdFgtD1BobZWvjtlb47rebVgyWoi3vPi2Dme4iFp/eEp6leQ4J5HK9QDkx6wqCeCFbSs/qmtzHlY/ypY/4RSfIZICEE0k8w0o2cAWaajn2R6Z91q4HFKGyQgh1I0Qkfc0NUNLUMvNJmjXgTh@MhHI6@OdUJXFQAmns0YzKNmOQwhp6E1sI9MXOluG2dk13W1aYL6JxEaK3BiSsUeMoVun/qAEXeaP2e7i5qTxrS1FHwSBYdOLVo9BIw8gT3XjUjZVrPoP2H@E/CfMP/JPNIw2sakxUQydJphdrDW45L9EBLRTEOYGduWde5DMYMcThSGAiGnS264tFev0dAhvZkNyrEWVgyoEyMguJGQGi@ajWbL9oyzVCst9aGy85QQUOKAutGiND3rRmakvnVqjRxvyQm6DyreBOlGJ30Q1AZWVzCPUQHRisHoZeJWmv1hsKqJCQRBhgEDymHgiaLBrp8wk9Vob2PqCRWnwc9pzBLWCBLTotJX4BW4gbjESM8Iu4iotYAI3aMsQTLBh4Qth50ZGnKHD1wHYEJYgR5zCCxySuKtOFDySlNhvKZKC2khVYIQJhPIjuJq7WpWQn8oisYVr4VszoLyX0z@xmdOfg/axerU0wrLOowqt9hUcH0@iBBBc6FUJfXaQrlCCqSUZhku9Fz7TD4NemuIJiWFagaLB7PgnZm@Pvh/2/v6/bSRZNG/o6fo4GRAtvhybCeDjWexwQm7jskBnEwu9rAyCMwMIAZhGybj8zsPcd/jvsp5jfsU99ZHt9QSwibJfJzd35w9Ewupu7q6urq7qrqqOqUNfsfk8aHkCYlxouCzwqJYhC4uijwteV4okjLB/WqerLZQjCDr8wICMHKx1RxZba5XmxeLvHCI@YpqdxqSc0JyzlW49HwFkpeyGmhPVbW94PBcgnSKkQMJgJfnbRTEoElCePatg34cP96MJqhVqTaDNYe4QPIQitjIZ53L2NZbGtLaohUBgIy4BKDL148XjOiCl0/7v/w1ikmp1ij@JdmA1wpgMFqC9w3WgXwmIx0YBP7EFu0DMHcTWy0jkaejAvxfjv9LWOql@i@//DIXLpkPv8xZkf/9Li8vkbLaBNWkj3xuBxdkI7BU6CaLty5og4EdQnOa0F7hYVH4HSwAYyrGGtwIoaRIcXvQvED2BZ7izB74kaSoYOWEJUrqY7zQWIlzj1IyUyOCsnXdgZ5xMU6Y@1pWeGVlCDZGIU6qpxWxSUEiPRKcldCcmCZYSmE0ng7GDyFAp3skeeMkIqvFc68A/wEOlgIJZCL7RYpoYz6KG1Hk6qbXoiRMciIQn4pUXscGEeyBcjzG43Ur8dwTCesbqGgi41ZqJ6YRTq8uj0lC9QE5bzJOQS0rkc4kqCq8g6UV35lhEDya@F4hDCijbKoUMVQo8O63DN1T4syhK@O@Q4qZnc2/yu19a1DvxtbMGrW@vbQ2O8WEgCXIHo@8m@ld96e@e33bE0Mx@fFq3ln88rMQuzsY8Cq2v@HQxfxeMUuhVi8FxsJ@m6PE@BLB7yg4ExNbZ5RJOykoJT7HAzwVlJ5fkK9CAWXCCJeKzZHiQjQqzIqj1t5lcQyL8Kg1vtxHs8Zsqzjbym@l8MU3eRPz9GDNVKc1uwS63GuzaNN4bYNWQ5dxlq48OvyEPc0ImQtmsEN6eApLhxd458xwAII@MdMdKaQyrg6UFWDYAKJ@o7ZR7aFmT@UtfJLqPVTKiBpCvhugUOJ/8PBmOo92WDxinWGedwCJx10gYVCaddhlX2yz0u4I7BGWgl27ryOBI47mGJz@fvL2jCET2RvcVeoLGsfw8mWBiiue@sNOXTCM/7gZdH46fi22c7mX@dyLvEYyvHEXEcxlXuwE2xUQSX3YRjef3fyOYRy7kwU77sFmjrB20gjQEqeoHL8Hvcy5dcZjxygNh@zh5@F9A8701ulmDKPudMl59OqGKIJq3A2SC7Ra92ba4ST1V4OxPV0gX@ANGpTWHiY//kXPxBGoOj15pZ1loBUEFLLRYMa2Evd2gJdB@JafnjscundIsA4aXZgeWGnkwB5nbJoijBISS@FC@v7oxpvhlEarMQK0r/BC3I5PhjFsfh0YGTJhGEMARYY7rbFxN4IJtNcZ2qhqZeIQgIY0CigEoGvdm47zIA4GIfGZOAjZMRWWYauRybpTw6W5MrJRtQW5LiAwjQpV03CHAW6@qTZEo3bS/FCqVwQ8v6vX3lfLlbI4@iiabyriuPbuI7nlije103Kl3hAYBHpcO2vWq0fnzRq8SJQaUDNBH4zS2UdR@f5dvdJoiFpdVN@@O60CNABfL501q5WGJapnx6fn5erZa0sABHFWa4rT6ttqE4o1axa1qqoZQT1ROxFvK/XjN/CzdFQ9rTY/Uosn1eYZNnYCrZXEu1K9WT0@Py3Vxbvz@rtaoyKwY0a52jg@LVXfVsoZaB/aFJX3lbOmaLwpnZ5GOlr7cFapI/KhXh5VAMvSEWyP2BL1s1ytV46b2KHg6RiIBwieWqLxrnJcxYfK9xXoTqn@0ZJAG5X/OIdC8FGUS29Lr6FzRuoRqsC4HJ/XK3gShZRonB81mtXmebMiXtdqZaJ1o1J/Xz2uNPaFcVprEMHOGxUL2miWqGmAAdSC7/B8dN6oEt2qZ81KvX7@rlmtnZkwyB8qeFfHcQmqlonAtTPuLRCpVv@IUJEONACW@PCmAu/rSFOiVgmp0ACqHTf1YtAgELGpd1OcVV6fVl9Xzo4r@LmGYD5UGxUTBqzawAIAE9v9UIJGz6nXOE6AFz8CsxqKcy0aTlE9EaXy@ypiLksDBzSqkluIbMdvJM0z6GCrCWgDvEjPsUe60NZbfnXroFPYsrQXL//550/HtXJFJNS5YSL4cA67zqvIwZT@DXYa/yP8DB0AdJ2rm34bL0pBid2vxkLVyOtbmAPBxOjrC@OBs2opu1GFjY12@32pXaq/brTbprVOzRAaj9Wg9J4grD1QypR9xLgytKGhUFkoMN0PQoQ6/AbFwZ4ztQQ7IlNJpv43tLmO7RHoitls15HV0BSCgJVYCnvw1B0JANbFpZGssBgvHjRJUg/9Hkh2oIopBT7TacNr7DkXcj34Z/xr8IM3B@0FrM4sSmezfWfGaICCqprhRsjARP9I@w5oXyTJe47zUz@V05tzxl0zg7cKoYekrENlZ85w2E@Zj1S/cvqR6ulofUIWjZoqC67H4QWsXSBj8jmYJJmQ45KZUs9S@E97Rn9MhQ1b0NBQQk2RCV4qRKlvuHord4lkZUMhSNQ8yCjzvS19X/2ASm5ue2c/8v6N/57nFjoNon8pbHgtqndJf95ccgGYYGTZBJIMpL0xm9XqgFhGAqVf@A4KXmMhvhUJ9@prh/Z1IAkIsjd4L55WH3bj6WCuYw/r8Ot66e3R@ckJLJ2I7c6r3Zd7@4Z/iPm9xX8/Yjvk4UlnuBPYx0FOo0/aLDkGwYdmiuaOH7A/MXA2iwUxnEMNGr1Eq5l/9RALCZw1gmSpgxd0d6uHwSY2KFHOmK5LInPmU0Pxa@zMlAyQCnXVxN6M7DmJ@DbISsQD8tB0uKBRm@M/CNuf/mqK@x2SDCRZjHxegXONJ7zuJbASnbT13JsxH4NgkUxC8TEfivs0wLuURL4gjxHpl@RtbRRBsMWBxvlKw041AYmnUSyE1EPJuxuaeEdWW6lc0lksvPle8hs8fpTuAuQ8YHuz0qwBZDzxa6IOHCi6stMtCfkSw@vwiFq1dCDQgmBKpGjuSVXVN7Nqs4FQwfhWtE6FAe/7Vtlok6gIJ/@WBH2bORVNoQhnX3Ks/A2cG9cdCWVfWWPlb2XjEwzLNxkz1e78NgxV5KNvFVTkDJHpq@hB8P9EmsTAPwCNE6AH1NJcKtaiJEFlWoH6SkQZ3CkjhmY5Caipv/oYgLnXB@ba75i0DM3JlQBJIEdnoV58JCeSXiqGAMjkJnoWaPO36zp8zeS1DarT3xKmrI42mHFnNEkJuVeorWIJbnrv0iKxy1J2G/xhCpMMs0Jr8BSqir@x4nZFsx5UpogqL557CQZnKmtqdhPPM4IJT1yKFMmryR5wVk7OMrUOyIMrbcPp@udPIJber7QIbgrN4Si09kurmiIUgD5EfJb7SXGGrugMXc@J@K9wYv8m@RSg974lL7yTDgDoaYAuTgjneVfIu@Sc2R1uEEOGTo4PATSRek6@F9gIH0sEgoNabs0MkJa21Tsf@zlhf6dhfz7mGBP6WRCqRIZ9TCSGY7wMEHiG7icWb@0FoDxcr9vMYtnNhmuJO4ciedgsIetj2GXHdacgOtrYb8DRGizMjPggjQ7O2LuZSm8Q2M8GU2mRUEI/NDOji92JFrjNcOwGoeYNQG6Yoc0F@YO6NHLssXQQGczTeyIFzKt49BBZmNxa5lt5kToIvhwATcjJi4h4IPYwJRmVYoJKByyHKDjwfOUCZonL7RyIXDD97tzpT7j3owg07jpd389LAwkv1CBVx@Qx05lx1yeuRxYNGAq0gPiUyLMh7cru/HSHkjfs0S8lO4GAjq8Sga8ReoJRTz6/HZ9JJVRsKGBc2Tow314aBhOptC0drXzXq/z2LqESp3Ddr1TGyPcqbBIXiYuxv6QU5I2dz5XoiE@8bvpPH/GJb2xzis89nD3wBu3nUgRFhFFmRZvt8jpH@OF5xYeBM@3qNlGQZLr2BM1vpPq4Y@JFZTqUThQde@Y5C9AAOtnBPEsw2qm/u9fj9rE7tPsDd2CDnobhFXNe8fBxQY84YP2pe@dRRDFnHNIKdRfBM1nD5aE2/pYeO/gzOOj0Zs4kpR@BzKaLEmZbQC2GjvHxrNXfr4i/J9ETZ7/Ozm5Qya8jbw@/8a5BN91fWfdFPq4ynxYgALnAHUZOZ@iY3EGfx6JqyZ2ktOMOVeDqoQIajlciLWzt8/1KjL8FEtEBbwhjhczSkYfeCdTMVmLc6s6tLnl0TN0ZrFtlB@NWvRS9tmxMggmryHd4ClEQ@Vc5rSplmOzO0asDHxaryb398k/GHhD4CvTzL@K4JY4RaInrydkAazIpE9JnC3Ahd@YBrdG0EsMqNujDLjQMAW3Po1DDnxerqEGniiAUSaeFJa7EGZkCxQcTX6TasOS0F3SvdVIkTXIUQBGkNEvlVjOsozOr7l@jt4NH3Bxml8GF6VhCTmlIryJVB6iECfRCMCc3Osrsofr4jNneXnfUIgQsSgKGcNAyS6YSSnJBT2x1izoea7lTWIwTEerJU8mkN3MnyTWpt3LtiD3njqN1x1xFpE8RZivCZrnZJdIWF/i42Dei@ESYJkwxOsUGHkL1lZ59No8ScV5s43wrtheP0GEVzYIzWX9T8ce7y3MfN8VbDC1VG40/pQh3dPna99@32tDx9uoVRMJk9apNK0Ybl4z2gh81UBEy@VRan0LEfRL3CD26QDlstwu008dnJVGjB/DKgUx9CrkMIT3RDd4eObguTXoZ6EjKVOdT/iLlC5xza0FHefn0Fbps4gcGiFKxkw7sUGzBDQYrwkcUa9FLtdEtMI8rETwdss@u8nySiPoEoxgHadxh995We5HOX@4zpLkPCbQKvlz7AUjyFRZrtecEZYkUMMVjSOH3aGltul6/V1/bFygHELg2ffZu8AgepCnsDN7m3rmGf/RP7TnKwEFTsmZoRoUnQpuWBpgLoKX0hw6rqyj9DabM8fCQktMIFAh@ncI/W7IGOkfv5XxqY5V5d4FFTElunm0m5kSjKgFD8W8kv5yKLOqS4goAHMYY6hfzAAGdxAh7PBQYOr1ZiPNCiMoxgorFPE5LeEk@ZoEPScx3JKossLOrlcjFlfhWh5GOBQKCRXyZABGQWeKLBFBgo4vFRSvxMr4/QQkQiBXvM8VhKOSohGnojxwTkPLl5cxgRWnlhZWTHEwfd3bN0Eefv@nrtzntay76FejjY9hK56NfX@VCX0PNbm@Hq4ZqAj1MvdXQRyCFqSPsrwpf938GuQRqDuRKwj3QlIyQlCF9vzCfIWiZoLdlfvTEAZo4DpWMoeDRYVw6T6qiUr/aHLAWcnF/2J1dJOnIAD3hv7q3KmZDYSIjL5IXY3K0Z@MuK4QksSZwq8duoaZL3hRoOCGPE9BvlU7r9sT75smJrgSLq4VyNBo5091cLodMfKWHEii/LTQlDdxsuHS2dzMcZid3f5@@v8rS2o8ZpoeeW1AatANDApPCy7jTPsfZIA5QFEungcAj99ZBXf@m19MDWvCEEgcPho1Lsq9YV9AGNPCdXt43OcD@JNhg/4kdxP79U/iz785mQVNCUcdQUBuod3GbUKdnQB580UPfL/@kioDhwqy8mWDfMouHn3AHwTgxGixyBjXRLCTZP/HGGQ5dS3zAnGRPE2RRiVQ4OdEr5LgInjAiUdDFaAgcZgnndjAMzqc8LKLzOoJTG5OK2lFe9hhpUHf6lfkklWj9kIBtBbq8hd3cQm9fSyT6CVO63q8BlvkQ0F6r9MiepDpEp2hh2OrlDA6eAKMXeStW9wkVMckmJmn2eGkkajy6mR/dwTgFXTdJFlCRATS81JMVxX3iJi7m@R7SMMcwJE50D9xaNe73v25p/Lpl8XbW6623KlJQBQ/sZ62IHFf2dQsinQHQDJTTD@iJ0ZX/SMO0PokEQrGAg6FPy@sOVmhjBcN43in@fJcqlUri2WRrS5RKR/CAiX6OSqKML46ORBmzqODvb4rbu7v7vOaWzU/w8ki9vBdHAINvm@1cT8vwE74VMcANtnvSIp9li8@s/Wft4sHhvpdtlY4us9k@PPGtS9mS/IHXMWWP6EfrB79QJpPJPut8evbN/T7@bpUvk8@uWs8ml8n@PnIZkKF0M3Ors7QduI9mplfGBu8C2lvyI1V6toe5XGVVodIjjOzpT7C6FMRGx8tuyLcex@HSGrvRcbT3zhgToYAKr0I4oqq8gSHyI3uB5ngYnY6DDniw31AiV/ID5fp8tqIM92NXK@CfqmwQAlJmvXUANJ5wLKCT3DDGD6QHY88ZowX8lmRe7p5h2PB3MGtL/s3@IO9J2LxIic2c2LTEZiJBf/DOhM0L81l2gDdxcDH/NoXgaAHdDIU3IEGP9AeKXIyQ2zCeUQAkQlLh0FR4fDO6QuOz0v4wfFKGr3t94wldDckmEjpkwiobn56N72FYPkGJ@4TxhMIZ85j7gwWFttRiqDHtRMUfXxSBbI8dAYKWR0yQggtN4kkfVOYzv6x6I8faoNhMAoxkrb8@oXmPL2AvekYxnfmILoVBoxT8yG9xb9zn4F1CG79w@wECdKDC6mSOwkaSG0k868AIyqCX1E1BMZ56/yTzsa/DwplhxaD5/xQaE9CnJzrhno3pHZ1j0kemf2LgH69oTSW4LEXb88mMoVUZ3Qxng8lQnnkRiXDk/NbueSbhiBIghsMR1IXlGUaGAsx8cOdQGLI@LBx6vBBdF7vOM0EmXMXpYGb45EgjQvaHFMztXyNz28wOEBPFDswDhJTvytezB0MPST5TmVv79vQKcy1QlmYxmPG5GdnzMK9OBGO35yOdIcjkch7MZ@jKxmRq90e2JTbO3ObUXlRh2wLJZ9bJmNDDcXJGSODkk03HdU8hzD2SQ0IU8btCnkMYvT1cyGBzHlscDRoMGlI1FWSCBpwEIXYiSjq/hsYqQseAqz9jEHSUlxZv/zRSLrG08qKnkYQUdAH@oWm2NHUM1YI@d/yJkzAYVX9mKl6QlW5wox3RwS@s5JjWW7VNNR15PihgucT2cXfqO2M7tDlNhobBiUmeZfcF74s4nymxB3sjyRt@8i/zQf4AxArkyB9CCW5kpgu3xzKb8SSVenLhyeD4DX0fQeE54/viZ21kVXlWTuHgI0rKdz4e8GIZ2aEGTHtgwoyokuc/QOgN7T7gt7izF8iKFxup755mzdYPF@PLzdTF@NeLX0zCRC7JapdNiw15mK1WLDlXYGfMWqGfyivNE3wvvbgYhwtcjMmti0/vJQkAkWyq9UP28tcsIHSxYZqb2YsNJkhoyBCT7MPtZRF8dgnNjTAW2Q3jiblpqsFPfZc3Beyt9BfHkF@Y/BewUEolmelBz5n2ABTFANE9BKjYZV9t53a28zugCfWdeXrq3OB@m/Zurpw5iBIeqrOw9Vz8EuKGECHu5569Dy/n0M9Bf4zJoGlEPZnQQi6hcppTO4bPVlAnwzwB5YHKKSQBhriYfhkbDx9R4bcEsJwqSxkt2HVQ474U7p@eO8J2bA/XtWh0CHMkehmwjwiZUNMIWTLeSg411XRJUrBZRhxfOzDICASGN7uh7RZjd5yWwpqZSe6jEI1RM0PM7Rudo0tTNDRDn0lhKvlU5A@/e/nf/7v288Zs43A7@2EKf2cbP2/svdrgR3iAXy/Ur9uNw40DLLZ3v7HIgg4Mjy//@/9A/cO/Axz8sjiAfw53Fay9xcZhukhVft043IOH/PY2tPt//@u/oA/PWGPDzDbP2pYgxPYVRY7tMfEufBdV7CWrpclgWcnjwoIw2MMQdHP4gY5R8@1XOTLTbUivilt0/xn0Zr4/itziyTFrRq5CbMlQ/hQgGXGFIjaQZpDKhaInNN8N5baBzBugKf75PLPngQbwT@nO4Tfpu24899Bl6BmrRTCAKW4R9Hl@OMx9l/DdOwoJ5VOyr0RIVO3kWvvqxT6wwzvXmQ06YS8JNV1HHfvOucogH2ac7g3oVGNv6P44zd4CS47y26@yPTTuZ8mPOzshSOnJIvMLCIIyGwkohuR0aokpjIA7gr/wjDlKQKA/8c@kVHYOkLInTodtWOEMT1Ck0SxX6nWLj4exO5lAlE7RvyDAYx4SmVZDizy/GEPNWr0gElt@QS5HOq@J2Lwj51iZdCTN3rCUwRYEGOoDWgdVfzKlaZ@CkKjWFCBwkYzd7bZt@S1lPEmowHPLeHLtDCfFBPmGQW/wJjKQ0CX9WcxcCSU9QAtCOk0LHcIaOTMbVPRigt6gPh60MMM7CvislXRjWl18svZkWanVd4sneKb1QNN33PQdjChKCUE7Ps8EuXDGQi/Ga0sRTZVTp41HarENQ2ueSoE1zdAfxMDjYan2MCxBdociIIFqQXekV5k@bBbpwsAjdw7H7LFpkfOAGRtB8KOlSgBnVc8yKDthuxluDBaIM3fsFNBDmW@MwwiIokraMhiTALT0WcUOSzDUh9rEYTQVobAjltyWxrAfksCBsZQCSDBwPN7UAh9sg3cPH7SEoyX0SaDhJWEiS/UKpGxRQTUcBUqqxY2jZsZ2qlZH@Ml6ejIXEC6P9CKRy2@/2Nnde/nqW4wZfyJ7Gw8GK2VQC5hc2wCDJOoUKNn4vlhMJBP8ChN6LTeJ0OPA4gEcunXdmYQVPz4t5nMSWC5BsO4oMRVXl@ZKAhlAnDoZ3BFAR0lNE6nUd4UWduzyomv@Cv8lLFWbGQ5NzfZw8IvNpNfG4R0HRFCao5Ezcqd4PI4Ls02ZXTCvPmwh/EUv67i9uoP3U6GvK7M9NHTquhiUMHVv@tc6d2TY2i@aMGGA4LPpokAa1GuHI0VJp9awQllUGhyqWvRFUcFrLfcAnXJxS0CZj4HDNIPJgF7@tvQ0xdmRhE0I8zxgxCoeIWquozo7E3eOXVE5K0cRk5nQBp4PN6N7toJwB/shgK/UTjDzkdbdJlAXpkRf9lqtSRYb9En3lQtcDssBVyDTY6x0B9N6aVRRazXJDbPUQ2TJEy8O/IR2QVUYR8QrBmY@9zgpVVyr6gUSRC2E0prkL2KWf56jkyzASR9knKfIy4mC5iP6duB5lM9bNpYwpUcpFYKB9PhUIg4g2m1yCe5IroAjSo8VSmPFo833o5LLJN4pygPsa6pObMlBT5oKKGqcM4v4tMD@V8@OLVGuwD8nH8oWCspHpX9gv/2EWavxzUt88wVRPVFDQASVZjjyuUWfqZ8xRAmYJWdx@pIAQVx8ybCB9UjyRgpWqieS9jypW6G5fRlwBbKrLYVwZR2VkwSzppAN5IlU3sl0JnMtSoW@wMar5ZVmSxZW04JNXA9PbI0mT4JWfUhMyjVAbEdBpBWIgNufBAzPHugkedtSd1GMXT2J5@kQy7JCBWL7SRbIHubZlZR5iC22JVtsF3AcH@IL4tsHeYNvLwszxyO88fTLeCO9PnOk/y2Yo/LncMcLyR0vCrj2MHeMO1OHViSK6KSkdm4Mx1wtaA9udwf9AdqHetpP7ETO0gDQgkeXktkUD5LPYd9WLCciFf9hK7ofoZPQ9u6e8YWd35Gd3yngmkuPZed/aufTv3Hnd2Xndwu418SMvBTtZPjrb9fjQCRMhV/EDi@Ku1zM/NKe7sme7hVwN40Z5j@8p@nfqacvZU9fFjBjAh84cArXh7mZJZFS47haDdwtMioDcQqzAsZzpYm6F94nbYne8Ma7LqK0Lr4Y/1cS/1e4GtFTHclqazHKvi7P6ikHy7NkyVfnYZAV94T7K0O99P7KDSvQR@QGxYs0GbamUlEBgdzij8FpUyaQH4PV19981sWZ13bKrcSZYTUFmjXCvBlMcZZ8qbBKwPqEGXmGlrTjZv10638xGUb2TzIKDZDHob3De4bkTqKrYDhW/Fp2RusOwm5InSPEKpKchOxMRnv77PJk9apGiS0i@2K8ksBHbZwuGTNQOZoHEJmMgDYZWV9pVeiaq9QLfgN950LxXZY9/iIu/VZy6bcFUZeKwSpS2dLgJ3kx0NO2d3cf2gO4Vgb/4ATMWVD@gVn1/4LDhWX3j1IPqdN@63jehpYsytDzdHMZgWVEuEzpBspMC3hlzPgK/Q/e@8mntg0t2zIoK55hHL8tN9B2YV91uk6vfz348afR2J38PPVmN7d388Uv@YRhqOT8KZOzFirvG2mmWM7XnJgmIkmb01rW5gAEGuaTbDUJG0KS@XzSbBUK25emwPk54nxMfD4QACARdewN8Z4kcrPws4fTULIHQzS216Ojf2@GMedAstTQHl11bTEvCPS/Tuctgd5g8m0HCAkkIjtMqgOr58Q0TboXRl45kdQhF5KW/lPv6rQ/qrJ9TiQSEiX4WaUDATS2@EV9C02LTC6XYhOYj78MumFLCdtk/JoytR6qBZJPt3cuzQKQ6QN9QYa/toczPhFM/WL6njDOzI8kwK3zmBc53EVyZihwQUP6gDZAv2OmZI7glIv7q62roe9aOz6MVgD@MlQ4RCvtxxZMfT90B4DBVHCPXHd4iuOrWrAkNSzxKuhMkAkRw5rf2MOePwoqW/GAnSpDvBPuI@WQRWqHBiZCCEmMnr/SBcHU19isKy3Ffn08bACMr8hdYQmUji9WWiqwxCW0hoZy@tCmEa3Hw@vNOJ14TCcC5mz5SFCO6IDftPcb4vtaHUb/1p4O0LDF1rY8tJFxMjA/@@TwP5OTKTZRkZxc27swr3zINMPMJeTi@7QK5dTyS9B75UtsgNYd7ABen6u6gLtZn7IbPo70Gig/MJ1DHMpgkb1PYDvy2VsxdX5PCnXJJCIt5ce4aRfmbmTtKfoYp15FBlvRAafXHpJLvbhkeSX4/ArHGXOOwR4wtdmdbEOczwawiC8Cn2YSbshhTJeyKAkRA@Pc/NEJ3Lm2xJX8IfPrSEy1xQNpQ3n6r80g0fiKzilgLXbH2BIv8cydGMKHCAIczoC8GbciYmP@z6zYNld3F0phP71lwTLS5dCgxnfXvdERyD3az6C8eoI9RF/HlwgxuAyzwDIEtdRK12HcG@SnZc7GI6l2G3P/tNuUaqXdRvmh3U5yKyxMaEKQdu9F6ap7M01P7euRbY//nu14Xhqv3p7MDKMDZD04EMnKWTmJoVb@p8xkAeOQ3kwLmadfkMiBb4xEIhxletxoiMZxvfquKeibQWPScYdDR4oHUkaqTbt4R2h50JkpsYmlPPVrZGNaIYMupRTHntcgXLiHOLjtNrr/t9spzxn2tNHZCJ7gvzfNt6eiSQkHm5UG5UNsxBRFGBkMgCT1FBE/eFquHTc/vqsAFUfDQ@NA/YFCh1TvYDaYDZ3Dgyz/5XfebIGiwGLigBYo32XpJdTNcuWDK7e7gD/dwa2gT8WEOvovTB0Qtwa3zj5U1mlLCPZcdxYgmIX6CFRCyzKCqoJeGQS5WrkmCsLu4pENCIJKecBJ5WFgyKC3EMkXyczAI70@ZYZbljefSGk0yT8z2GLSEsm7rWTM1h8eiMabEtDy9WntqHSKGb/eVeqYxnLVWFz128A0KMHStQzJ8FcOT3PHIaGCvsykxBr9GC71PYnG4Xcfw@9WdKNeeV3FfI6rMWeSFsWnXCF/H/50iz5VsV/oEgr6dr@MwQpUTk5Lrx/EApW6pX2PvqKFOfbriqZqZ69rmIISU2euatEd90HT6Lex5Rjyqs/YdBsv6vDWordq@ahWfoDm/SF3JtooNobTY62mjmvnZ6sXB@kinA9D2TB8RM@b786bRrimv1jBhKF1yhJzbanSppb0SZmbq@AflRoVUTmljKfaJ/J1GTojBd0SC4sXFVBBae10PBBdLJWoEMWYQjSuma5WjV2O7CvQn29mzj7GgRY@3U/m@zN3Ih9wqmGO3wLHuqY@3Xedvrl/YXy6T3DbxQQwdOLw0z0vVhfjJF9FM0tJRPXJvIS3j7RpRIhRrtSr7ytlRY@G9jlUEohWPVZffXp1BtMOxs1pFKP8M5bMPhMzQqmlTZi@EOUZQpJAMGUYDD@j31V/il61aZrk8Hb/ysXND3bh7uDGK@zmnu/7dJGILDXHIC19cYwkXY@RE1SH0bvsT@zub9Y56gvCrj/YIRBrQSu9GmLiCvhv@Lt38MKQI3rlzmbuKE1prdXwcq3Qd5xMoc8@AJhcq2vjx5iq0Z58CbmXSLYWb6lpRqmdT6rHvMk3QOov1eu1D43IarjEl/Z06t6dT34f1hQ5NW7wJClIq5hAuglY1wZdcWHQKkYX2M38ecm1tGIxhXgoZakLg8vpzI66BGFiZrfpIsLg11dNZiJa2b0b/0uSDXeP35VmYTrVsdIfR6igdw/QKcQ5Kwml0fwP565TaPtfkmg6C/5OVFu95lHK9gfXvECAaVa@b0aFFiQ/3UutUx5ffBnBl7dfvWuBQEgtrGAPia@Pdrz69sAK3xsMh6sEX1/Fmy/Ly1KiXFFTU//mq@TleqVRO31fEeXq62pTvC@dnlciYvMUz4ZuHT7Ilk1NnT5eCAH0oxMqreGkpkB0MLSC4uD4HIuC3fA0HG1GPd@gaYmew@Egg1nS47KGblH18/2M3bET25JqItDLC3EpnqKgoVry1yRar@hLuM4d3g5alHDlgdCvSTNqeodi0q0niYYZDpYgb1u8bhXvsVw2CA@lDY1HKUTfgLIIOH9pLi9C1@vW3o6rLUkROSoEiebajJjnw53zQLFb7tz2cueAYF/VPYkg2rUy0GgK4D2MWcf1/nDEoM3HEQOt8I@mGka1hChnRnT55RMKckFYxSWy4RbNgvBpmAx6@4ezoEiqlTDO1KRdWlFgWXt0PVlniurnqMFB6vwpKvHW0gQ2H5vCx@5wecjyK/uXnPavQKe36P9NfxeJPYu3HrrkIv743lpxqv8QIPOB4Y5dCiObQvWsXHlXOcMracQ/Kh8/1OplNAk3oluDvPg9MoS@JzaZUD3d5qwbWFUFLkbZKGauuicK5JhrMXQ7MCtwJMhYRjvxPDhqZPAc/AIP8ubl0EmxOoinZYLMGckwNZZgMJuI5XWejpm5QwhuZ5kfKJPmQ5OXq@P1FEt1F2vWzcfUxfz067a9vaL@uu2/iKtPllk2Fkl7FWLEfxYrhGh/vdSHCA0wqwbo4Um@NHzm7zuA4t9vBMn69ZXjp4xOf9QgvvprEP3/u5quWXknrvJwzcq7MZVn67a8F1d53ZZfrmRc39S5zL2WiFrsPoOdpd3trxXpT1qRlN3zoUUpftDQ7vfXsP2Zw0aW188fODJE/jVyf@bIsS3484cOraF/jdyfOXJkj/46CQ4NkZFBJANpFD9U3aPYhdth9wq0axKA8MeHREi0aEZQCKyZTmoNMpnrNobq5JcphF@q630po7HTDlq9pdlaKI91yViFy1W9DntvvC@dire1cvUkzoNjiUCe84dN6W1S9H2yBZZc/EjeN3FGs2mbTctrU1XEAkEnQX/MMbw/dpKhX1JLFb8k27BsP8bVmv1l/XrmGr7P0nP3bupi/LmHNyypEO@RPdM40LejlMp4qfJp7bwOA1tvfMZE77q/z8C6k5V0ZBPnl3D/LTvoqzUwykn@4sqTOtozWQoxg89byXgHbc3USbE0vaFrB6jRW0xyz6@XTL/hNtJf00Z6vTY2v6aNzfXayH5NG9lsXCMrlqVy5ej8tciKxpvah/gy9MW7xgui8HanztRxxquWsPAaBnV@H16PtZz/aVbAyA7hj4Y/OyKVHrXfy@XoJ5BO/Hss9EVIGxwePh6dwVilUF5reOgCtD9wfD5nv4gbI6YKH1P8pvRcYYs/q52lyQAfMsTzHfa@Z6tukvc8TBIorfKeezPt6OcplJoWx4i/BJlpU0uRUw/uYHibUtiBlkN8MM5L5Xug0FehMony3SDxfMuOqVsw4LGNBH64X9OI7@W61E5oYVLiCXHnxTh@M4nve@xiGXg7t5YcgC9bScQoeakYkggRC2ZDB5ROp7HKpyQzarLw6R5kQgIFj/er8YjxAI7FNdbreankal/mZb4PmjdXEnRpnGPhRUJOfODLrtPmivgxfyLIHM0h9pDnSHR5hH6RROHBI7d5KJVzuLZIWnokz0py8nFaIGtaYg5LEP4bt@Cv7TIeOxHWG@B4x3DtmjK6TNhYOY9ouR@qw9WNmLkUCyNcLU5iw5NfIHg8tVdsjhpfLwUjEkdILYDP2JeOEx/ifKoax9aPnPpH1oeeUiyCiY2n5/7UTibvV6wNPMeovn95AlLFAqKbcXGKOm6Hq1AjJEjb8SRdQM9cXRILafFKKXPl9J1Q1rkA@uq5JXfiCVLlzB07X0BC/vsoEWM4MDyBfX8Te8lGoillfLRNYkWaxAoKIPLPuCk7IaH6tTwdZtdV6LCOWBL1SqksGs26ODk/OxbVs0YTX9RO6MNp9awSc6qziB8WfftTBG8pal8GqR/XXnnDgHhD/FdahUmbVwSXYy893YjZ/bF/hMsfmWNE@1C0VhxlUbyMJ6waocLjNIiv2ALYl4EiPrh8ENCAc2L8G3BBPDUe5otHtQFNIxi7wrvBpF64mThz0EG8pLnuGtUq7PCyhHv1b7RTagJC7E65WuyIWYzipOUV9jx1JcZnDByTkO6Dj5EtpJqpbskwVs47KpBfYfcL3JzkghD1cAoNT0R/Kx3Bqls6blbK4m2l@aZWbvifIs68GKcbjdJdDn3TQnDNSHB@8srp34yjMaYU@jburgmZY2djw1ozlKspPuQ10xm6QKMljOj29@TKaL3j0ulp6ei0IkkTDdibOx2px2LO3/bEnl1He8BqrIq49YvBbj9NRrK/vEpG0dMhRLpFgxF5F9KtZb1IESS0aTwWec7x4oC0H68tmwoS42jlMkyHILWNaWBmUcNALhDpjkjn9YD0p1rUMV2nI9Om82sL0yONnTuaaraflNb4nxDIvWZ4ZU5GV@bigitzFFvJTv0UEr0fxFgmDndyuzIe/LG4cCaxTHUUDvIXE3e46A9deIYHoHi269xmxzfDoYFbfnfQ64UHQX8@/GYbb8R0OteuAGz@Pw)

Skipper `` ` `` is used to separate Fission 2 (not supported in Fission 1):

```
R`"12"`"420"
R _`*` *
```

Fixes elsewhere:

- more Monkeys at Mornington Crescent (`D`  `N`)
- Whispers wormhole: `R2`  `120`  `0; Romeo` (avoid `"\0";`)

Comment: how are you testing these with the TIO 60 second time limit?

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 First argument of the test driver is language filter. One number - start with that number, many numbers - test only those langs.

Answer (score 0):

## 423. [SGMJQFuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/SGMJQFuck), 18355 bytes

`````html
# 6 "($11k_rv+'50;+'51;5 5 %$\--$[0=@$a a tqx\"  /*4veDhfdIg/\"" 3 4//*{{{'F*Pi^5 6-di26qxy}363qx}318qkp16[.qx]"8=,k]\[] PPX~_~)"xvyx" \( # CO"14"#:9 {?63#k9 # a   k zzzzkf kf k zzzzzd kf k zzzzza kf bfz "'" #\\
# 1"7"//['][']     ````      [>.>.?]~~)[aatxy iiipsddpsdoh (22)S ## &rem      / \     <!--    5mxf xAegguEayiuFt@.7.8.2           <MZWWWWWWWW;WUU  U UUzR                       ]++(--[     x        Lear,x :_a5# 202ø!},{P_<Ám/e!<ÁmOe!<É}M<ÁmS15%!!%BB44,222%!!%BBPZPYAAA4D,5P[5?4-0!<½!!22<2/!]ss1]'[kkX"204".â'_PPQss>3Ā~>1Ā~>7Ā~v 7 999993 1 7 3 1 8 1 1 55                                         #z#1111#y#y#y#_#        {! 1>?7ДOq#t#>2/Wr#t#t#q#68#r#t#t#68#q#63#r#t#t#6v#>#</Wr#6}#y/===Wr#7ЯOq#>J7Д/Wr#y<Wr#>5/Wr#t#t#6y#>-=/Wr#6|#>6/Wr122! 1退           coding=utf8         @ [[[["472"?]]]]******<
# if-0//        nthteo 18&1& nthieo nthneo anet\#184 O@ .^R+ + +.V>!/D<----.p/112\11&if -%*==-* (echo 335&exit)else goto e&WWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW#WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW;WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWR Cicero,
#6!@`D>>if 3>3*>++++++ \        / 78"oo@"  Thurio,   ;L // >"082",,,@R_++  xx-----xx._+++  ##### #######._   #### ##  ######     ####>   []   ###### # ####  #######     #### `'[]'[]`###### # ####  #######    #EEEEEδΘΔΔΔΘΔΘλ
# endif/*   v 1 >>>>@::c>>">r"{\>>>>> @ 0:8:8/_}\(*[>]R 10G|'53' Sly,_1111 \)\[ >>>>>#####>#######>>>#>#>>>>#####>>#>>>#>>>#>>>>#####>####>>###>>>####>#>># #####  #    ##### ####  ###   #### #  # #####  #    #
#comment -[v>]-main=-[165]-   ###[@,,,"279"_]#-$y2222]>252O @>>>>>>> h$s o#>>>326>########>>>>##>###>######>########>####>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#######>#####>###>>>>#>#>####>###>#####>#>>>>>>>9
#[[/]e]    >>>>>>>> @!:!8:6:2/_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>;  >>>>>>>>>>>>_>>>>eeePs#v##########; ### ## #####  ## #### ## # #####  ##^##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####  ## ##### ####   ##### ## # ##  ## ####
#cse xx xx xx                        @,,,"361";@,,,"362_" ;># 23-2g_"01",,@_       # ????!?!??!??!!!!???!?!??!!?!?!!!!!?!!!!?????!????????????????????! :1*23/5%6E2 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiir-[>+<-----]>+.---.-.iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
#11 cbbbzcba aaabaca1tauaxayatbubxbtcuc 11  Page,_ xx xx r3o5o8ox xx xx .-#351$#&  # 329284   38839237137637028538937437711 37239942236736836636911 289364373   375393
#~[! R++++++x +++++++++\++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++U.._+++++++._+++o+++o--ox#] Puck,
####################################################################################>121 *1220*1211k*1220 2 2 2 11 Caius,
 #{{{{]~*[~* -[>+<-----]>-._+++++._+._@]+-}}[._+;;+;;+;;+<>;;+;;+;;+;;;;;;+;;+;;.._]}++<^>--[^>[+[>+^-----]>.- ._+++._> ]<[+[>+<-----]>--._++++._+++._<] ]g[>++psg--.--._+._q]+-+<[<=oC<=oC<._>>>>-]^>[<-[>+<-----]>-@@+.---@._+>$]  )++$--![+++[>+++++++<-]>+._+++++.._>] (  {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{{ {{ '4o'6o@<<>> }<}>}[<}}<<}<<<<<}<<}<<<<}<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<}}<<<<<<<<<<<}}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}<}}}<<<<<<<<<<}]  >>\[/>\/\>>>>>>>]>\[./>>\/\./\/>>>\./]  [328][]  [[[[.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.][.].,][.].,][.][.][.].,]  [[].[[[
#* *#p 173#*
#`⟪`⟪\⟫9999 9 9e:
#{  
#/*9 999 99 9999  nMn MMMMMMMnnMnnnMnMMMMMMMnMMnnnnnM>MnMnMnnMnMnnnn   //`. :-print(186). end_of_file. `MnM   Egeus,    @,,, "286"_+1y2 #<"67",,@_␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋'''␌`297'print quit`sssMMMMMMMMnnMnMnnnMnMMMM''';201-1|>print;exit 0␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␌␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋␋
#|9 e:
#( 9 9999
#<<<#//-->
#><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=99><!--e$P+++++*D*+++1++1E!sss \font\f=cmr12\f352\end Gaunt,
#-bqbqbqLzLzLz TcTcTcRqRqRq TzTzTzRtRtRt MbMbMbTqTqTqAbAbAbTmTmTmBqBqBqMzMzMzUgUgUg\␍331;"$avdxddxdxz$x${print+191}$x";exit;# ?>\␍try:eval("2?2");print(349) #\␍except:import inspect;a=9;b=2;print      (not inspect.isfunction (lambda:2)and 395or-a is-a and+391or''=='-'and 241or-b is-b and+1or 394)#\␍exit(0); '''ss';@'␍[puts 59][exit]'''
#= $1$10l0c01b1b0l0i 0r 0h0h1d1 1 1 0e 0y0y 0mo1d0y0e0e001d0i0f 0g 0n0n1 10mo0n0t_0t0mo0f0t0g0g0f0h0r0r0i0001b10c 0c0l1111000001_1 100|_ Ghost,p\
[ ' "`e```.1.0.6i]56pq["``\/*]298 .quit._[`\']"\"put 294 bye!\`""360"print bye! #ss['];#/\\/;print 24;exit}}__END__/
###\ e>+@+-@@@@=>+<@@@=>+<?#>;?\:-._++._++++._#/<?\>3-++._6+---2._# Helen,/++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++._++._++++++.>!\
[ ']`w`WWW(wWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWW\wWW_WWWWWWwWWWW/wW\WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWwwwwvwWW//WwWWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWWwvwWWwWWW Henry,_  xx xx xx xx ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho ho hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi MU ) ([])({}<(((((()()())){}{})){}{})>)(({})){}{(<(<()>)({})({}<{}>({}){})>){({}[()])}}({}){}({}()<()()()>) (<><()>){({}[()])}{  #(((()()()()())()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())) ((((((((\'; `"<<rc|\;puts 409 #"`; a=$(printf \\x00);b=$(echo -n $a|wc -c);case $b[1]¢ in 1?)echo 54;;1* )echo 242;;4* )echo 78;;8* )echo $((9999999999999999999>0?166:244));;0?1??)echo 50;;0* )[ ~+ = \~+ ]&&echo 282||echo $((346+010));;* )echo 58;;esac;exit; #{IO.puts 295# ['];  print (0and eval('":"&&(defined?A)&&290||(defined?pp)&&190||(defined?__dir__)&&13||"_"[0]==95&&108||109+1' )or(None and(-1 %2>0and 9or 247)or eval('5<<64>>64or 68' )));[exit]; '"';"#{puts 187;exit}";'"'; #wWWssss{}#(prin 45)(bye){{{}#}#}#r"\"print(355);400#{}"(prin 199)(bye)) 46(8+9+9+9+9+=!) >* * * * *[[[[3+4*7*@] ] ] ]sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
###;{e=1}={e:null};console.log e&&39||180# Duncan,\
__END__='''  
#'  \
''+ %&
se pr':;@echo 185 #';se pr'-';pr 89+1/2*518;exi
ifdef ss 
1     ! !
2   !    !
9      !!
2 #
#xx xx xx xx xx xx
dddd d b ggggg g iii i llllll l dddd ddddd cc ggggg g ooooooo dddd d ooooooo iii iiiii ooooooo eeeeeeeeee
echo 353;exit;' Lucio,
#PLACET,2<- #2FAC,2SUB#1<- #52FAC,2SUB#2<- #32FACREADOUT,2PLEASEGIVEUPFACs wwwwwwwwwwwWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWw W
jrzaeeaeuee_wuuwq jii_iullluiiiogr se_eeepaeeeeeeeeee;eeecisajjarpppppp ⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘95➡
▲▲▲²²²²▲¡▼¡▲▲¡⎚¿⁵228¦ₔ₁₉₃2♦10♦10♦10♥☰䷩䷏䷏䷨䷏䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩䷩⚎ֱֲֵֶֶֶֶַַַָָ  
밠밠따빠빠맣박다맣받다맣희맣희うんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんうんたんうんうんうんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんたんたんうんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんうんたんうんたんうんうんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんうんたんたんたんうんうん  
♈  ↨↑1↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↨21↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑↨↨↑2↨↑1↑↑↑↨↨0↑0↕→
♈♈  
♉♈  
♈♈  
♈♉  
♈  
♉♈  
♈  #e:>*****[[[[828+*+@+*99] ] ] ]*****<
♈  
♈  
♉  
♉⠀⢃⠛⠋  
#-49,A,-1                              #
#-5,A,-1                               #
#6,A,-1                                #
#X  
_+------+XX  !X583nnn;XXX
_|/0110@| X X  XXXXXXXXX X
_|/00011| X X   XXXXXXX
_|/1001 | X[``]````
_|/1001 | /183nnn;/283nnn;
_|/1000 | /01-2%+?/123nnn;
e|/$001 |  ;nnn383\          #/ff*:*:* :*:::*{,-?\ 683nnn;}
e+------+101-2%+?!/ 1a,3*3a,-?/483nnn; :n@04+7*aa/
#+    +
1   *xxxxxxx
53 x+       x x     xxx
1  x*  xxxx  xx   xx x  x
x  x  x  7  8 3  n  n  n;
 +xx xxxxxxx +x xxxxxxx  xxxx
x  x   x      x   x
51  +xx        xxx
#  
1   *     x``   x  x
49 #+  xx+x=>+  x+x + x B+ ===+
#  =x x  x===  x x >8 xxx +++= +
#+  +x + x,_8=>+ xB  x+x
# =+    =x==  x +===+> x x    +
 x +     +8=Dx B=xD +  + xxx+
#+ ``=>8=x>  x+~ x  x +x+B+
#  +====+x>~+B+= x x + x
#D~+x 8=++>8x +=   x+    +,_   +
15 + x   x  + +  xx   +  ?   ?@  %"18"_     !
1  + x   + x ++  xx   + ?@    ? R`"12"`"420"
1 \+* x    +  +  x    +   +   *
1   ! x  +x   +       + ?  !  ? R _`*` *
1    ! x xx --... ...--  ? @ ?
x +   ++ xx  ++ ++     +
 +xxxxx  +     +
  
#  +
+ *   +
#  + *
  
write 224;bye; 
  
rc
x = true 0
$x || { echo 350; exit }
a = 403
{|a| echo $a } 406
exit
  
#=**************************************************+
  +  +$$$
#>"3"O._   +// rk:start | print: "69" rk:end       + Milan,
   + ; + * •#407#
$'main' *****+ %++ %++ @@* %-- @@* %++ %++ @@* x' '
 -+3o4o#  +
  <++"269">o+
 * *
  +*****
^ #= #= +
 #+=    # Paris,
,   #
,,  .=#
 #+ OOO       =#
 #^=
+`` 231 =#
#  #uuu# Pedro,
,,..,.,,,,..,.,.,,..,,.,,,...,,.,,..,,,,,,..,,,.$
  
 console.log 178# Pinch,
  
~~~x  
main:Int  
main =248 
~~~  
  
x Priam,
literally, print 249
(print 164  (exit    ) )
  (  *)
begin write         ('288'    )end.(*)
print 61
51 outputascii 57 outputascii 48 outputascii quit
#<<<##>  
         print(85)
#<<<##>CO COMMENTp]] 
execute_process(COMMAND echo 296)#[[
  
T:251  
E:0  
#+IDRIS: main:IO      (    );main=print 291
#ppW<#require"stdio"Stdio:write     (293  )#>
#ceppp  ;  ;   ; ; Regan,
MsgBox (0,"",169   )
#cs  
You can see an x here.<<<
  
>{-<<<<<<<<<<<  
>> R2
  
>> -1
  
> 398
  
> 397
  
> 176
>> Output 3
>SET x TO 120. Robin,
>X x.  0; Romeo,-}
  
>--  Timon,
>l=length$show"\0";main=print$[0,0,0,233,0,146,157]!!l{-
  
\begin{code}  
{- ;  ␉␉␉␉ 
␉
 ␉  



-} 
open import IO;main = run (putStr"159" )
\end{code} 
ppppppppppppp;pp 
# {{{ {{{ {{{ {{
#!ZZt >>END-IF
#xxxh  program-id.h.procedure
#xxxg  diVision.display 230. *> Titus,
#}}}f >>IF 2>2
#}}}e
#xxxd
#xx}c
#}}}b
#x}xa
 
+ f
#&
__END__
7&::=~147
#!::~322
::=
*/
#if!1
#endif*/*/*/*/"n=410+1;print(n )""";say 338/*
#1""/*
333
quit
 
:e
 if -%~0==- echo 341&exit
set/ax=2222222222
 if -%x%==- echo 330&exit
 if %x% gtr 0 echo 337&exit
echo 336
exit
 
#!rubyperl
; print 0&&339||340
__END__
 
#}}} }put$343 {{{
 
 
#]#47|>print"""]#
let d="""#\""";echo 21#" """;log 380
#[#[
 
[][=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=[=][
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
]x
 
[[[=
x] 
x] 
x] 
x] 
 
[[[=
]x
][[=
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

MoOMoOMoOMoOMOOmoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOmOoMOomoomoOOOM 
  ;  ;  ;  ; ;;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; ;  ;      ;;;
 
text 0 0 405
 
혀어엉.....혀어어엉....형.....흑...하아앗...흐읏...흑.흣 Dionyza,
 
⌁⟬⫸⁜⫷⌁⌁⌁⌁⌁⟭⫸⁜⁕⌁⌁⌁⁕⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁜⁕ 吾有一數曰「281」書之 「（》十《一一一一一）》十。一一一。十十十十十十十。」









































































































































+ f
 
#//-->
<attache>Print[194]Exit[ ]</attache>
 
<script type="text/tiscript">self.html="<p>302"</script> Venus,
<script>d=document;d.innerHTML="<p>344";onload=function  (){g=window;e=g.external;d.body.style.color='000'// Viola,
 
// Adonis,
n=e===null?334:[ ].pop?257- -[10,,,0,,,18,d.dir?159:2,!e?77:d.clear?5:58,d.compatible?50:g.XMLHttpRequest?49:d.nodeType?8:55][[""+[].pop][0].length-!!d.head-!d.fonts-28]:d.dir==''?312-1:308
d.body.innerHTML=n;n-416?0:t.innerHTML=" Elinor,"
; }
</script>
 
<h1>404</h1> #//<!--> -> Aegeon,
<p>301</p>
<a>304</a>
<b>305</b>
<i>309</i>
<u>310</u>
<c>419</c>
 
<style id=t>
head+body,text,h1{display:none}
:,a,i{color:fff}*{+color:fff}
a{-color:000}-a,b{color:000;-color:fff}
: u,-i{color:000}
:after{content:"258";[;content:"276";]}
@media all\0{
:after{content:"260";color:#fff\ 
}:root:before{content:"316";color:fff}
:before{content:"314"}}
@media \0 all{:after{content:"266"}}
@media x{
head+body{display:block;color:white}
:before{content:"345"}
c{color:red}:after,:,c{color:white}}
</style>
 
#^^
#*RV3>>[0]{472454523665721469465830106052219449897} ()//~#class C{function:Main (a:String[] )~Nil{83->Print();}} #~
#%RV2>>                          ()
#V2->=359
#V3->=323
 
 
22-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-12-12-23-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-13-13-31-21-22-21-12-32
Take Northern Line to Tooting Bec
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Embankment
Take Bakerloo Line to Embankment
7 UP
7 RIGHT
7 RIGHT
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
7 TEACH
6 BOND
6 BOND
6 BOND
5 RIGHT
5 LEFT
5 RIGHT
7 BOND
7 TEACH
5 TEACH
6 YELL
5 TEACH
6 YELL
6 YELL
4OURfuorfuor
FOU4
FOU4
FOU4fuor
FOU4four
4444fuor
FOU4
FOU4four
4444
4OUR
4OUR
4444
 ; ;
set ! 57
set ! 51
out &49 &1
out &56 &1
out &50 &1
When this program starts:
There is a scribe called x
x is to write 179

p now 70 dollar off!
p has been selling out worldwide!
More 91 of this
How much is it
red down one blue up red down one blue up red up one red right two blue up
baa baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeeeeet bleeeeeeeeeet baaaa bleet bleeeeeeeeeet bleeet bleeeeeeeeeet
#
AOCOMM9#""C""Hata;re7^ >Exith,8,3"t5"giogrlstd[*u""]!!48 2\0C0+---2ya=1/;b= 16|>?4o@let ,0,1*_e#8g=:s561?<p>3=0+@#osHe8;""an,Pri,:s9   Ford: Eni^ x._,_  \;ncepp headCa 0 ::
 ; ;:在ｕ
+ f Dorcas,
 
*/
 
#1""
#if!1
.int 2298589328,898451655,12,178790,1018168591,84934449,12597
#endif//* Alonso,
#1""//*:
#include<stdio.h>
#define z(a) #a
#define u "e"//" Angelo,
const char*i="25 10 37 1""a c #FFC0FF""B c #0000C0""d c #58007B""e c #0C8302""o c #FF8000""t c #FF00BC""u c #008080""h c #E60001""i c #CAFFFF""f c #280000""k c #CA0000""l c #CA007F""n c #330001""q c #E60000""A c #0040C0""E c #808000""F c #00C040""G c #008000""R c #800000""H c #0000AA""I c #00AA00""C c #55FFFF""K c #AAAAAA""r c red""g c green""b c blue""c c cyan""m c magenta""y c #FFFF00""x c black""_ c #FFFFFF""V c #000502"": c #010001""@ c #090909""2 c #000002""3 c #000003""4 c #000004""HHHVahtdegggggggyrggggggc""IHH3aixuEFbGGbggbryAEGRgc""CCH:afyurbgbgggggggb____o""ICH2akmyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""I__:almyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye""K__4anmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy_y_e""HH_:aqggyyyyyyyyg____m_Ce""CH_@axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""K___aaaam___bbbbbBm_bbBab""K___________bbbbb___bbxbb";//"
//\(
typedef int known,macro;int x= 0,    y[60];macro m(){0;}int f(int a,...){y[x=0]=x=72;printf("\x25i",!m?195:!a?124+x:sizeof' '-1? (1&*z (N)?234:!"\??-"[1]?67^*u"":*u""?218:402 ):*u""?37:z (0'0  0'0 )[7]?75:"\??-"[1]?77+a/2:77);}__attribute__ ((weak))int main (){known y;int i;f(x,x=sizeof y);x=1;return 0;}__attribute__((destructor  ))int g(){x?0:puts("198");}//()) #}}};print{408}{{s{{\}*/
 
#1""/*/
<<<<<<<<<<WQTkTTX Antony,
 
 
>import Prelude;import GHC.IO;import Data.Functor.Const;import Data.String;import Text.Heredoc;import Control.Exception;import Language.Haskell.TH;import Text.Show.Functions;instance Monoid a=>Monad (Const a)where _>>=_=mempty
>instance K Float;instance IsString Integer where{fromString _=0};b=x#x-- Arthur,
>i_= -1`mod`2+c;data B=B Int;_=B b;e=error"#//";f?n=unsafePerformIO$ catch (f e)$ \ErrorCall{}->r n;instance Num(a->b);instance Num(  );instance Show(Q a)where{show _=""};f= (^ );q _=r$ (d.B)?4;d (B _)=r$0`f`f 2 64;class(Show a,Floating a)=>K a where{k ::a->String;k _=show$ (id ::a->a)pi};c=l (- x)`mod`4;g=[here|here<-""]--[|]
>--W Banquo,
>x=0;y#a=subtract 0b1206;x#a=174;h a=a^x;r=pure;l a=length$ show a;forall=0;z|(∀)<-5=forall;b1206|let _._=x;negate _=3=206+[40,58,0,57,55,26,16,3,4,-78,0,1,8,5,6,12-1]!!(l("  ",0x0.1,1e1,(0`id`),k(0 ::Float),toEnum 0 ::Num a=>Enum a=>a)+2*l (do a<-Const[1];pure a,h pi,h(0 ::Real a=>a))- 3*(l$(pure$TupE[]::ExpQ))-(-q?6+70+z));(!)=seq
>-- Bianca,
>main|let p!_=0=print$ sum[last$ 172:[[b,0,170,303]!!i_|g<">"],0!61]--} 
 
#1 ""/*/
#if!1
#endif//*
/*/
#if!1
p_;
select 192;
.exit# Brutus,
382-9/5*50
quit
#endif
p=sizeof("   (\");print'(''72''          )';end !"    );main   (){puts('??- '&256?"101":"92" );return 0;}
#if 0
#endif/* Caesar,
#}
disp 49
#{
}{}<>
x.
Emilia, nice chick.
Ford, big fat cat.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Emilia and Ford]
Emilia:
openthyheart.
you cat.openthyheart.
you sum you fat cat.openthyheart.
 ␍
S\\
#<2^2^2^7^MAOAOAOF@#@@@@ @␍
#<9^7^8^MUOUOF   @ ## # #################################################@
 /._++.x._;#; ; ; @   @@ Ford:                                           @
#   /!x._+ +.-.>_#   @###@
 \?     -/!  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<>^+++++<\>+++.-.
rebol[ ]prin either Value? 'disarm[223][270];red[0]prin 221;  -_#.---.>/
#x{  /<+>/   K yya+- Ford:  & >g+$02y#v_"693",,,@_>10k !'&* 001- #vk!>2*+'P:3+'D'34#v({7f374e8c-69e5-44d8-83eb-0a1c248957ae}+<>2+^@             >0  ^
# {              @                                                    @\
''';'#{' #'}'}[']
#@[[[["272"?]] #]]******<````(print 346 )# )print 379#s()****
#<<<##>␍'@#'
#ce ss~## Ford:
#endcomment K`250
#nocomment outtext("155" )
#/`psZ283MIOnDrFe
#\!|!o51   ;" Ford:" ~nJQ  p'34' \=#x=4;print(1>>-1<2 ? 17 : Inf16-0|>sizeof>2 ? 162 : √4x<8 ? 201 : 225+2>>1*2 )#p⟫try {EVAL 'say ｢27｣;exit'};say 237#⟫say 167#{{p{{}}}}say 235#]#                #]##>/1a97*.;  /8a7*._/#print  (171)#s-#print(365-((1/2)*380))#s|# print(208)#sCOMMENTprint("65")#ERi521@<? ? ?342;![["172"?]]]]* * * * * *<es9#
#8M`|  <esc>dggi2<esc>// Ford: ~- <~-< ~-<<<~-! `=> #
#1//  >>END-IF*>>>9#
# '>+/*' 25  >[};}]+pppppeeeee^*n\               \! 99              \*n*n*e*s*s*s*ee*n*n*n*e*sss*e*n*n*n*ee*js"(*)//dd"    <<  --># #    _e 5>1  */// **/*/*/*/*/*/*/--\)∙226ｐ|_|_X222999612#
`````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3L1rk@PYdSD4UdHw/IibYFaRTBJPvskkM7OysrqyVS9lZnW3RbJYIAiS6AQBFgBmkpXJim6NQytZsseWJY9sy25ZHs/Ka0@Md2JmLcfIOxH2ROyXCcd88g8o2Y7dsB3SP9Cecy8AgplkVrVsbzgWJID7PPfec88995z7Qlfzhj/9aQIv8sSxZgPL8YlveD7pueaZ4YrkzozsaqZXUHMch6H23MFkZNi@V@USRCHE0uzBRBsYpG9avuFmiWcYpGtYzjn4q4RsT@yJZ/QaYMsRYhvn5NDWzR5AIL5zatjmS8MFvzwhdw3rcnTpE90ZjTS755Gxa9o@9S0Q8kQDS3@inxKt6/mupvumY4NXcSmJ0pKtTMhDx/UMgOTohuc5CKuyFESRybsapDe2jOkVyIpCPjANt0doLsauwfKiqOT9k3v3rrrmyOcFxyb3MIdXvPJkb@I7h/5V@AWyNzBsjahiRVSvehYBT75hleWyfNWrBFVl@KZ@NZ0y2ev3TdsgD6GsVz0rRPc8wdNdc@xzUJXknulCNWtBdRJds6HasFK3iDEa@zMiMELQLCuqZI9oHpl4E82i4ezJqGu4YUDP11zftAfk3PSHxB@aXhSPhvbGmm4IPcMyR6Zv9IhlQiSnH0AB0HaPnBqzc8eFug9gOrY1g4iGbvZNjBLmAwDilfKHBoMz0mZAOLYPVEI04kE2LCOEluYSEP6u0Z0MiDPxxxOfQN56pqd1LQDanZGe0dcmlp8lXfCDKqHu50PDDqgawIkA4sRhufpoQrNmLIhf6/WIDAQN@Tg1iAlYo9mqklwO3InjAtYgVJijABglcFZGYwo1DHXWd6qkIMvgfxC5YG41y3OCzCxnDT1taLS0zhDuE9cZuNoIsNEzKE7fP3xCPN1xwQY3hmUN6yYwuuaT7W2SPHh0N0kaUbWIbpeLqqhOLqAKEqEnOdOsCVBIvCYcqB83is1hlSU3klWSBLSoMsnnSR7ab5moBUCSIlfAAIxAzSlwF4laJnkF2luB5CBwToXGXQQfaBAkLxeSWUy872oD0zIY6AGCLmHbgTgqPOU8yUGzyBVzLPTAsfosqE5zUSK5MimWSKlASvCskIoK2cA089BiCnAX4QaIFcgjAFJzkGNZZcAWjQKIGAlxn/S1kWnNghRoEjopKKQEUKEwCkBXywAF3rkc3jm4ywht@YrD9odQFUPtDMALlnmKvMyI2BnWrwQvaWtLonwTGTNL3hti8oBXwGihTEqQfBEwkocsANrVMiRfkFlBvKFhWUG0oYfRaG5LMtyQ8xLgogxVIwNOZURqCW6wA@tUgUeqwBBV4HEq8CVVBXMOk4BwWFdFqOdiniUz1LxTSIilo/ZoBQDfBzAKYhz5oYJIAghQawRQDTSQByrJIZUUcgTyD3kpFQlQQFkh5TwplwjgsyITqB8F8oUkpAArViA/CgIDOlCAEBTIkwLYVgCokisQLoZsJYf@EDcHcQE1Sh7i5MEMFacU8YZ4QB0KJKlAmqpaWVAo5E0tQHkLOUq6ahFqtwR@gDcV8qoCSSG9qmXwx7hlwGEZKbuUzDJEaIgHqBVsC0CLgIwC5IfChbBgVksB8WrWeKh1kfGzmN0@Ri1iGykiGiGqjMWDdx6xCVmRAQy2Bsi@ChSQo00J3vkoeUsBIE0Eb/RMyr0t7EGUCEOlLCXIj7Sxv0CbUqQ5Gs/8YeSmMjcHuKoJnNEYaPos8oRWmI08F67FHLqqlBEvAMl5dPWA7ToTz1oAiQx5lSZlnJnWwq1M3XqG1uub3vDVIq95mkjX0HzbPF2kUihkY0jVYh5F9FhyKuXiYX1TgL5sMETToixqCcOMnaiClrKsKDR7XaM/sQeGUCnH8kd9/InrQ6@zSLPCnF1zMIAefAFHydJi0l504VygObRyOejcQ0fELqbpmtC33yb6EGSTyLPC4FcqCxg5FWHMtC52@QLIatBFVLBT65tT0r2t0y5lkcEcxZM@NMdh4OrawLHKpYlMy8UYbVDMvSzLEXvGqy1@5Jh2KkmSaW7OQUfE5M94Nw693QfYhWGnjKQLna5DRYoF@0zZYbeZBqQtSwDQJVsoKXUNXcPuGTsrg3a2IRzTFwkkAkKk4ZyhcEt7zKVkPNqrdl2UZUEE6hmuSzAsCMBelva/3qTrGS8mKGQt8tWHDt2Afr@vmVaUAdqPaD6VDuCd9CC92XK2@64zop3NCPtXy3HGa2QZ6M3PEdB959xYZH3R2WvjsQUiFbgbTKKDzJxrVCqnInw8VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KRBHTNXSK@6DoEDsHQstyFqtEbdzOIZQ7MVkrB40F5BAP49gTy6qCEGToJNeQesaZhC5MHluWwzAPoYQGclYAoquB2I05p7mIIN1WRSr7nYQ16zmj5aKx/vUwKvrQRKnJOtdmUHt96FqNqTYC5YCgBA4tl4yAYlgNYk2AFoHFOiQ9x076EZRzFyRcKHRUEipFI058c2SAjuRAFKzxPM009u40Z90ZkDLFVl6kShHLyRVEidxVRDGHfMyBNRaQBXsTHbGGaZs2pSAQlzxUAFxglcyN813SamlwuyDsjQM9UEQDBjzGrMXUCY@19kAs1ylEFGAN2wMNxROJiVoaUP7A6QOxnZtQdmBYEHUBW6dIQBRETlNRFzmKciSg0alFTKKPxwTcoVMC8rwnl0E@dT4yyUvwtIagX@gT152R6RhqwhxBKF93@n2g3pfGeAggyKhH9JkOzRMqmVKPN7S1MddzKJvRx8uFXdg2DQhjo96y/@TnycAA5INM20etEQl/UYzxmBaEIkSzmbxra4AvLIg@nlHkcIlFjL7jiOjecwyPkozjnkYMABPzjAFtINDa@guWNEL5HWjVpnpHD/hP0MgQPibIrSwMJhXQwruGDQ1IB9qEpg@ViDW7R/qgkMcEWVRFNF03xn5ALQ5laqYdUwke30OVgLoKATDRG3Kbu2T7Cu1A0Ih@YhItqkiY9XGgqWjIcQOtX6DiR6SVMv5iza4lDyHOrqTOP8cwSzl4zq/Jw5g2DNSPKKuY@MhQkEea@hA5oo88h0rd0ObcyfXig1s8eXdEhH6UNuZGAebDiVLkhPlYD0OA27oOSBxbCKux5IBBlxzeAFrzRisgO1EmrV7cVZQ0EVjjm4COHNtZARWQGcHFIMs@tC4oMR4j79CsiBhpc/GW6gjZ9mIgCrsz6EnHY8eFlsFYz4wONtAqi1FXoKOnoh4jLZI7yx0sdBxJ7PZ97AshwtjSgBawiWFLBf1KA34BrIzp0MD5HJZiLMO01VNYQf7OaQfAiAl6VNs2UEXT3BkDAsWDThoSmhHTdYEZnmFXwXqisEsRKZ1Cz6D1eshfER203V9NXESK3p90zelVRV1HR/EjjzvTXNJHHd0F0QMaUSrZ95LpGnWnMWNevOSMfYlGZU8eAtJAIlR5qg9qP3QV94DRHM9sPcUvNTE@S/iJ3y/zaTBgRCapkfdAYbiaO1QikGhGp9Cuqa1GBtCJCwI8BXSjOUEPSUQPzQVpAxoh6JqVSq@rkUvgHi4RpvtMIQkVE0XMR2kZdi9KK0AE5iVeXpEl4bk6NQixvg1LgMFpyWknsYTAt8QEjciDgyQFPSw6UJmP@VHphjlObDqwR1JMIEmTi0gEhg4gRTNjgghi6qbfCYSW27dD8WWjXgdiA5kK2GYvHddrw0FPETg1BBapTBIkIvrOsY9tI5WG8mLgOcsNCE9AqfUGufCHLrQ4ap9zEAjQytlIySFig3p@ZJ5Oelcr2kZHDMRjqwPRydR9vsaBCMBaQ/0mrCaXsAq6bxKxisSL8Snoa8RLXbFC@SCYa3goBNeDrMRqOIU5CGh1JYpY1MBtQdD7M90KRAJmgsbOuFEXsn8ajHVFjCgbyARho73WUhkQbA4MDnmyd3K/HrRF5il1Tbu65GA5umZR500MzodxHxzeOdo7@vnOChiW2a1edZDMfLmIXe1kKgzsiZQX1epmHMYC8N3OzbAx4nIYngu8ieBMY6LSTIfOZRqi8/HR56@iBCQhRAdNAcx4XxFpWBgQuriu5g2vdMJkkMlAklGUMCwRDkkIMzJg1tFfC/PzZPLyJVbe1UyNA3fMmTXRGIDQUTq0w3giel4RwEKvbp/1iDQuyKKmjRMZC1M8ZJifd1F2vpoZKlDHSObdx/cOjuoUbDC6JtAgkueDLKW5PRFo3pqAIr4qDLA/MOkkIy4yjlI1zetKBOv6EoIXdUvWwAcAqPGIDhGsUVg0bwh5379aNuoq6BEFUDuFcFWujMtD@mfNaCwf2MXpqPiu6kWpx6KzipxW9liR73K3pRcKRilfiXdb@iLNXhwonTeAfiCUG13wOvUEdBEXUmQgVgfZP35wLeMeFSJBFRDCnHkWEWlansWh9iKYJOlJ@6CnOZYhfkA5Hk/4tCQlw6kDUfeoChoLfzA1/ZScZm8lDWEh9b29Q/VuGDgYuKbjGVRpQI0ceya3j3OBugc0YjuWM3DIFsRh0mGYIIhNa4u5N3DsazWkoSMWNYHTicB/cfhGG0NfY76k6iONFVda2cSkZnvnwKWVYg6RRDFEQUk0vPiRdqYBuhblPj784gF0IkpBliOzTC9AQSwORRea9JgrdSACJCQG@VlZwGj@8VprDz2E2AQgFjpgdFHEvYX3SkfKMUVpZfiVWXrPuYbxj5zZFdICF0ZaYIih7PDRkweHjw4e7n3Y8tVCYcmelytFQByk1wVZSBwyvGFr3WJNE4uF4BLQNlxsXsAFJqCghBNKE88Fxi1iEJFlYA3VsJnb1HvO0E566auFOUdf4SNbZyT0EBsfCxpEBEW7Z6Ey4rKZbezPkX6Gvj/2qpIErXw46YqgtEof6Y6lDSQaDzoGy5IUVF0OH@PohrcqBmTGmxksBhviAtFhRscRNWvkgPJC58eRNZAUA0/HrixzMARdGCfRDTctRhRMSyP1QEMAXVmKykYZMLUBboN3WE88I@13FLXM6FqR1bzEh8GWmj@E3egboDqloLcCVKSvWEnrdus2mQGXRkhXgSSIuEUHOTyCfYFFQJCkY6eo54fIodwCR02RV1AcvZjgmC5wKakg50tKsSCBWgZqGsisAo68CSPN14eC7wgAT3D6dNwgRoV9T9fsvrgVGMLMgtx3C4qaaz5rtew2COit2zRvODXdnLWbSjtdI9ejbAXh0zWg3qXiIe2GDkC71AikSd9kDT/radfZWU@jratHJH80DvocYUwe7oEg9dIBft0z4m0PI0hxT2lrKayEgV9JKwaELIzK4QMxJUGDgp4WSE/CfAkg9KJ4CJQDfCsWgSxGMyKBaeYPgX/kSGqfmtLXJVx0zgVcYzkrODQsjmfA8mggZNpCDjMUetAExwwCZiUJKhBKPOifZFmgAwknLrD0MVQTG9Dah44A1DkPhyJ97IJxzmbCxoaxSQZWHPDcE75INOHlTcJFGBoAv/7DH/QDOJHYJpI7GlIcYOGKZBdEFMlTZAHQl8@IT0caegaq8bg@4qltoiIictRXgK4rudkRfXeD8JDW6z/8k9effOf11z95/cm3Xn/yq68//aPXn/6HDeEV6piN7UyrJYjZZpvwyWuZv3Wg3tq7c@tOmeYQ5EnI/P/9C7/6t7/2S8t5X5Hujz7@2o8@/sW/@aVP/voHH//o4y/9@Idf//EPv/LjH371rdK1/69fdvT//okTJHmOQyPxBIP0ILnhEHrR@yC1NbdunV@QjY0NiL6xsQM1sbGzQzJkB54CPDeg39wB3yw8d0gTfDdIm8zbHGiwHlkx2ifS8XPR0PRhB7ilbqRyaRG6vIvL6SUZDptTEdr5Ka9v8e05nV2ifQHOuLBM72OlHdMlMpj396D7ZrZF5tcl3ZRaTbnVbl2kWr1MujWXskobtOyOiQ8vpaabiigK4Ia8JSWJF@W5FOVtSkNCIFEfuouc0Qk7tmIHdWlG8PfMKfREwCqBkOJj8pS10MkdHFr9ojEeztx4gGi8CuRTHHteLATB9TLI/@L85SWLHxeFlnTkUGJk4UAsxGEvlDTGM8YXOZbTlrS0Dinssc6E/sjxNel9EdQNMdbRJDeSkiBAH0J9GCRa7Iemp4NqodmGM/HiY3Qrhw4xdXA9GU6Afe8PzTFn6EMHKH0XYJJolgSRjBM@Aps2CqP1dBFubNbIMnCKAXpjukbHhMqnrZeOYig06TPNMnvRWHahOH4hRqnVaBwiY0LmwHZcQwBEQAyOLkii6924Rjibe0hHiq7xysCXdgHId03Dz5J7lqNRjDo20EKMGnEuZBEf9FmIcmT0OMsmQh9EC5HVgGv0pC2Ozm067hDYJZQGp2zUqI5GgYfkeOOe6E8hKpfCDiruybQhENLOSU9V1aJe6FdDP6QFQPYQqga1OBtUwtBLUMAzHVTtARtGCXXaR4/vHrCxBto5YXeE406dkdObgBwW6BlHhj3IkgOgItN2RsBK7TD@y1PryHF8phWDZd1IBlMyzdHE0ugYydVhjBvj6U7XsejQyU1RF@EnrqdZGhu0CX333n8IsvHTk@O6WI0FkrSz0Y1p47jd6mQZPg/jM3V0ljKcTvEYYfKbBR67uXBFJTKXwKOMHiNcMwmyYqBFU2vkGAS8UOQ5hl2rbkThFBqOyUiLhC4Ulbqf@f3@knOOOp8KyEushXOeOrN1lEvqkNtdBCqwQLiocilMHFCRhonWVq4NV6Lh2HIOINaFR5l6aHSlpYBD90u@Feq7WGqJ0k/AwaIJ@6FhhRNwR8bIwUkm6CUtnM0A0R4FWbYY0oC@YoxzCZRN4wwVdAkaRLwqaEETGwssNJfYoM2ma9oSThRxmxIJRohrtOGA1s1m9jzGQh3QjOngw3aDzQij5uEypUdiY9ebHQCx3aiFi9PWBcOUkskoGIVK8wYxaDHpJPi1okZLGjw6JM3RKDXOk0Donqqy0JqWDtqXScmjaOgTvtWa3pLVD0EmwWWHm7elgVGj64HW4KsW@iQpww76co6GYsO7@hC4C8lMl1EJ9TOx@47VE9hcEtAaYVoIVlAwoR8thwxWvRqmG66EpEtRWVTkqrFFlNfgXqnSxvUAsWWXESAUH8jlafbskjRPs@RM9MaW6YOIhPLEMFhVZF9doEnnszTX1WYeF6wHqZO9o3ffb8ptBoEbaTg/VGa1OA3X@YLW5joTXJkNJlzV4ps@7fXprL2J5QUhByLQqQTIPsBgCdRIlFBQIir5GJeLsvQN0OdSBhWXZqMsMdJzsW9pvm/YjObYJN16dLPZlCCZOk1@JxiarxKZzl@Yfcgl@EEWa@T45O7B0ZGIAl0qeYDzHFVojiA6gjCyrtAhJuOFr5JbvSS5hXHSqNxy0NRAXe8E8YGoa0D0EwNnc5DtDAw3BY5pnKLQwZnOCtGITBoLEIRrk3Sf4igClgJle4cBq67M/1P71HbOoxqvAsVnKCYB3anbVZQy0@LENl@IHnQvVNCEIIE@Bb1EfTNFOdmmkg4Wn41wghWEaiogQgmaTQI6E78JgXnSbtfYTDmEBT9wQ@zyPK0Kuhy8roRVXwdnEGQohCB6/RV51pSFSjuzuQoUXYgVrORm5Y/BRQjLoD1jZbKbKdrerzVklgc2Y8a491OPLn9c3s9QJZvMwLORWRo8XFxEmQ5di7S8pmh5xRI0MmQldMACCxKyhESwzj6gWepPOT9ovRiNOqTS5CJCuoooJ5eXFIdkUyUUh2BSCKuMeagVA2N64EBpHgRr7OMyAW2twXILbLMtjg8V7eX5TPRh4rp0dkUmFc74eDwmE5r2qUNnRSJTRxaVAsqBUezRqXU9Ji7YpI@loFEeWFh1Xe68UbdPHysC0MmBYNqZOtBh50ACBtFRk47oi45Ar0h5eanFUrLBUk7a04KZCC/eEFKolGngfrdrrgsKSMA1VOF7RTBgUkjPqpgXlUURr67GIUv4DdaWBu//8XEP8Hy9FobQIeA4XGToQBeNNSL011ZKEBUt9LG6Atlw8cQyNYoAanoTSF1zoUiaFRlWg6ZT0oIA3fwIB9iDmgUaxAcIljeQE8s5mx8L36sTWTXFZANr1NeFvbI6iSVFJ0NAbetRJDBhxzRoJMqiWCUYUzYhEVObkV29OVPhEiJCiZbV@3DiT9gTZNs3VqI5xvumNhiElAtaVzEktpr7hip3tdNJzxHGp4NIHi2uCLsoPR0tEqDbDyZHO2hcXXxWQLY6OnyvC7bowqRz@noTVXj2xBsLXapj95iNNoTRDSm4FnuuC2IG294iw3qsmRZ9vCUlBtCBUIK1ARKuvxRiSDOvoNnSujOUNYafncqieXbgOHU9k5FzayZax@P18VGvpPErldWxp6LO8LFqBEBiazwDBYsWOFj1@YZahW7JHGmWoPZixrVMe9U0/bWg0QwfjYMbEuiuhBuJHDsefWJp7sJ0A4lfG1S@NjwddAtPTN2B7n5MlJKoqAvmGC4JW4DExbT0EZv2N1chLNxMIUSm1Y3d0X1cKrmGet6CdbElirgQNEYOorMOJ7pzjvdagWAIyiZ7ru67Xq7M1VuwIcHSLQ165rWMf2mQDwcR30CS56Zn0MdqxJ6uzKivWyvdl4k9HL6LD8e9iYA903I8ckyfNyFo4AIW2HM16cZxaWq2QIey4@YbuE04t7@oUM0aOFaxPJA0eKyt9YnbRw4fvN@Wl0W8SFHewItCQcexleC9loOfSu7pmyqIbtdzcV1nzHhDZ7qKIQVzF@tLB6I@7ltYXbJ7cpnGFCU2xLcmYVzNcq7NwvfP0EmsQ23YSYxnVEAGOQ4jVMpg8F0mNP8sqeVvTq33dkzpGtjSmwoRq9xTy4BuiT6vVSlRZeUzxlBk@e1ZVN@aGBNjperwuPuREXQYb5@4HGR3MxhZx8F83IARhXoZ6HRvlTvsedF2I9PQcPLuzcLJMvMagzw9RqX3CRieoOF6jIE9GS/V3pJeZR8x1AzHYRN1eku5QJ/PylfKb5BxliRrz6D3jboO081woVO9IMtyIHrEZkKWLDfpQLko7kcmey4lTF0WKS/C4uyXGzOuToOiJb6Ubi1LUdep3jRwpSLZpm34M3y@JXfsOo71WWoKmCRuf3VAzxToktGbauya@BJshiCLwQUPhyS6/XXDCqz3CLRCwA@quzdVenyq5q1qU8DJyBFOFC1bV6eBA4eWNur2NJLqnjvp60BxZyYO0rA1o9Z6UTAYnlDEslha1E7P6RqWxl7TYv6meBUxt6JtB3OgOGfKZkoX89qJK7xjPIOymj1QD4bGyKDWG8RrrYeHOQSvtYGmDt7rvKeGoUvTA0NfF2BsQrO28bk0NRuTXXzHBsXGx@VmqCBYuKAxcF2PrIeaazoP9h69G59jDwIcjrSBcS/UDmJDArhehilOC@PqwYEquYNNSYdoAdhAsLRPjZkXvldGfDjToaImo7WNTsfRwbdoZeuWQF7vwuyhM7SHxpCtO45s66gUCMmngAPqsQdDXPI0Hi8thY7jwXIsK44HZDGM4ThOf2UaB7glEnfyrIzP9lkHrzcOU2k@a3xoWEumQ2MCfNxzfGdsCNS2LqiFQxrsuY7nhDO2P@tYyY0aLaAifP@s8N@oWw00xx@P6asztiYefdCoAt2x@iZ5os@WWNDFcI47EF86o64YOIrB@gs6qbu6TXdNXx/ilmFGkcbA6epD802ZDo4pkMLBDWZ9K90NMWMS4S46g0IP6HVnItJLPe5/jK/DdZUejJOwziAy3NC/rxqLoptyhbF2qnts3A9NpIpDn7HWxbbuVunm5@qLiekvgMbW5EQDmWygHQ3r8h4sJVgridC18Qt2GCwxWEulVHhFQVUwZBAQlHXJLq/SijWxXI49VvIG3dFP@yF7XovJYHkKHeIyY4OP4L5EOkvralZK1vZwMvCu8zY25twDaQUf6zVyujw1Nu4K3YJmB691GFQtCfetwbsD4sfEuHFioHDjzAANp1iC5pjw6sALamWydnjIMsceexKhv3beKFhuA2rm1ckthpvZaj0xqJie0Wfj@Gh6k0wG@jUIrwPozwUdp31xGBj5NOu0GU@ynQHwa8Eii8Bh2HW60srlMKurP@rehA8fGQMN18Y@MH1cRbiCKmj7WLWM5o2wvzDRPPMLEyjZOmLDrfhszsyNL6JE2wp4D7WBqd9fqogokwGCgyWI7LVE/uh0vS7Oh6aHy28iww1jLkhyjIiR6jogQq8IeXXwOTqFYNGA2M62laFXDRA74xluAJpR001jw6ZPBxCD9zotat1ipxszcT4ZjSde8FqdB7rAJz7AOmLszDs3AbjwArgmGWqWv3oQNjaaCIJU0N8tjKuTrJIvmpYzIF8sywTkLp@YKOeuIJw70PM@wdUjrr2CEmnabzl3hzq/wOQ27wXUrYHr1G3Tv3kAw/dxJUn4xsKwTsE5B3ngAT7F3c8KQThZjZEHsU4u2lX6hi4aKOzYmbi6gcboqIi4RB5AN/bDhbAmbq7Hoy7O45qN7ljQjMBgrWwaumNPfMGd2Ddy/@KN3L@KxwXFqpukvnDw8Gk6Xut0ufCbBMnwQKmFae3s9hViMm2Qpdbzy@XQodh/lx10c0RXrb4hzh6exqNTtnzXWaWCPJlBR7GKmU9Gdw0d57LemMYj56FjO9C7jIHxjY4Mti17aZXB6ogY7QFuPAY89N6YzDEFu6ZTYdKDNja6UI/WwvQ2fQsDfFfztTVdCx32oipZZHojTZhW13A/ouNZMfM6rXE5Q/eNKVUD1hMGa2uCr@tMesWhpqW2sDS54I0dx2ZPyj1leCkPb@YSwNrp4@1nb0Vc@72keq9UpZaL@viMLV0weuzcgHVldY2uY7HnDQtibJNNVGuuaXjSA9yGTt2KeSKANOXdyCtKN/KKhRYDkumZ5tGZ49VawQKkMv0M61KGmqs7OGkTGG5YMhLbO/4GdhwtJ2ez2V1A/BQ4k6ZPglMd35Qta9Qd0cdaBSBWm0cGJNPDdWvHM9vXptcrkw2@BLvNY8uMoj3aIVvCRl0kqSegXaRXK3BXsGeO6YNy3rUzuHSliGCbhv5Sw4Emh@JlMby65A9lkx5R45rh1lhzoQOhkkY3Ha9sMcvrpkAQsQzBH7qghkv@TSO04YkXK4b0JyMD5z2XJxLWipyON6SFdVZP8UZM1DWE4PA14BnRQWxMrhP21kqMCB7@j@@8J0Gn2inmw1MggEW9eVIZMj9x7eD1NpT2xPH8vjl9DPnGpebr2AYWqwBR4MVaAJq21hUCas@eWGxAYBBb9DPqUTVKoGfmCoJF2bJvCIZ9JtAzuabXS@SwXUTSHh6n6hs9IdiSjoPlwoNwQ1EULHivmNOL80BcUahIDLHTYj5YY7gKuechBwD5yfGFsUff0th7cvjg8Yk49pSV/dDeEJfgX5PLlva4q2U5Nkr0kebGpubYWqie6fnSnWNF2H9wKGKANfhmo/cCvHByaem1digyPFZT0tZqL@hr@KsFvvsnDx9kFvvvSGp/6DojIx333j8@zuJ2hveOV3rHY9@D1tF3pmujHx4oSnoF@QabNNdxyRUprYN0YoAWCcR4nx2R8UYhSnfGRu9kNjbeh04SObX3lskX1xbykXZmDrAVkspaRNGGSipiMZ@OLf8FJdlwo/e6@jw1x8gtdfqS2GvtCgmUEHKSm1stJdw0OX1VWiFyMDn@2SIp8nVqjR/sKmnePzZjiqKsw/Ox1od6JYW1lbUcYNUUp@WcvcVsqBEoI0LkJPhAVYL5xsXKJWEErFvCB46YB45g7K5dmXETgMi5uLLBnxv2TLMFlJYCl7ETSRlfNGJzNdFikTM89XnltFW03pqkdGoM0Xzixrz29@8chh5HzD2wvfvoKXmieaDxrIBoxCAuJIuPBByvwcO81g1cHPZc4NSsnxiMV9N9lRxrbs@xZ9NYU8FZXOzq6PmVURy00UCGZU7NVbxbZ@MzT1avBAnTYCvkndmSnBc/HyOI8PrLv6ooskxPP8G3IjPrFQImKTRpMzw6K@51chiRvo79sggO6ZVa1QNjiisG2CjlKuV0Jf8u3sDbS@n17PImv/INfvkb0rvmh44kJ8rKDQALN/iRghh5P3Cs86Ej7muucQM6bsp65YasV2L8JjiQmc5eBeb1QiuuBA9eK@ntxPDd/HjodM38koi8vI9y7XC7r7l0/cHACRbPM/vqpM4nYUN@qL004k34dMEHjOEEl4yvmEjrgiBm2AOTnb9G7jj@AbXdoC1E20RXzzWb47uT8RVWgkfVX@FOH4BS5px75A5u/FnIhyuUS1xbtNp9nTBFohEmPGrw/slemOjjY0mNpbjIxYdPlpxxa5z/@Djm5hrT6TptS5iuU15W@ixSfXSSX0p2u/Hs7A37KqBnA1YXvdd2uYzvvHd8vXWipjD0R1bo855mGyGcnuPTvVLRONx0vBgc/WBICSDkYysWdEEvYpoAw5M6HTy7pNNZRyUnxod0YBn6SuIbUxTrmYAfHBFkTPNDP/hMB42ytgE4pxHXPh4PTXsaWEYLd1zrRlIfeWGJ98ix5ZyTUOGJNZ@gx4Io2plh37ypSajkbu6Qc/FedwlP7BsAwWsdiu6s6b3vGK67KsyRLt0LLe@r6RUh3jsOA6zy3bccHCTtmZPRKm8aNZNZ5eUuNeyrkcxVHniE/enQce1VnmHFVKt3jLWgN27wG81AW1vl0e33VzkfeM4q54cTyzdRSAs9HzkTaD0hWR24ofTW2G60WmJVXFjxRF5v6KbjLsApRs7EA/HOtNJXgwofmf6S4xV8Uzc8EtiwRdu5Cvc9h3zeXOQzXoiXa7H03r2Fz/I48QRnCunuuIVx3U6p8Sz3RvJ9aQ6oZTXh2eboiu/itKVD17GZLR2f9wnPWloB7b5mmen1E6HqG2ZCkc0xf3KWW9XKgOHfi2P0/dk0kpyfWHTnbmDbV6EAA11PB1@M8OjqSyUXGxRgS0bWLHtbsOwvHIw0PT7kuHTkQjht5C2YeEyzcI8f3dk7@eDJg8D@eW3UDVMIT0lX77JVW9EajSvDKPQceekYn4I31KDvoiMoAm6ivjKD9sHegychOx6CSA6oxKPeYgNNEd8lqZ7raaNKJEE@DPcp3YW2h@YFJ7o/MxxhEhWK9Xer1Py1uweuHhV1c@jYAU/XauOR4R9P3H567UZWdbWyc/xgHVt9Lyzm8bsP3/tCuJCR7W6Gzit@fryXDc4xYqcBsD3Ynhge8p9K2cAz0svfVYpvKMdTllObeMroJt08DmEvL8lGsGEbPPhwC3iwRR0PIzTtiYF7zNnXVvz6JiRTryuFCtnBDxlViSLTNPEzbxV25luYWJNsXgTbr6tVZU426oSv8iTYAB8d4cyOIQbAeIAqFIoIpwrZ9MFnM9y8Teh3NcglocOBgo7nVIJNlOLHWNSC7e2Qp82LJ4dPDo5P9k6eHjfl9jzY/h6WwrYhtfCQjVu5Hg@FD/AGahg7lJweu2BBcvRjCjiM6IXlIvgdoeWi1ZeKtigUv4NxNi9sW5LoCQCSMIf8CTxLjfqiHARODHZYYlpBweEPVbYZn54pAHXEQPM0Tai0KpFXJTzWPA@KFfhf/ewW9cVvtlXxq22YcHCONIhdA8fpBSl6BnnzFaZ4b@/wwdOjAxJmcEE152bPH9YrBXbMeHDCGI/nAVj0qIxkECUJdVWvJ@8lATFJMUmq9MwGesQ3nkaWjOgBT3sIYm@R1CaFDxhMRpUi/Y@PpXlSxL0DaQibDDOVhGSB5imh4HlsJ0Ak5O7R4fsHRwTzf3CXOiOKEAQ5wY3kf/H9HvtIRniMU/i9OncUqBlQW55j9qp4ioNukEReUYOjYHoEjzBjBx0QY0o/OEEpj45xxL5gl6ZH63DxoyfC8xgWR0ZgzVEOEI/JPmZBj2KIvqIRfQyI4@hRcUDv5/SkwyuHAKbpQVvs63zseM4INCW98EB@nAMEtYh2jaZn4kEQWA99Z@JeaSS4K5ueeSmSPfyUH34wUKPfe4HMTmyfnRkWnCOUAAoVI16VJZs0s@zrMHwsYHJ7AxpJ1wDtlHi2CZKQXyUfAQXj/FuVHRQiCI3ktSgh6Co1Caj7xAIyPW2Ep64TYXyAh7@1XOn1r/ySNKgRMPtg/mpgnsp3wPa1wNYH89eZ@ZmEBColr30UJMpLPEN4KGhQApYRrm/@9Kf4dU8@takopx33LJMsyDV4KLUCKZBbmy1B2GzK9d1NDRDpv5i2oDlLW/kz4@6w3zscSC2eB3EpL0lbFxcXyXtbT8xnBVIUeqZafDGdzXPF3IvpPKeUX5yOlWJTfDFt8@V69rTdarbJkycfvuq8SvPTMzpKlgIC23/MK3k@Ua2Qi51iLnFawQ@CQQlPyUu4TvsE/9T8shcza2ju9oFukzxJtFr4KU6@xAPbS7bhTznFc7gYz2g2xIa40371Kt3UNH86I6Zpjr1eD25nSFKqmj4m0NRuQyNiESTSom@KRLgKo2mfTPeMwWByoM3MyT1/VyyJZVGNMabth1/8ILhqHzx9SshT8vTpy6M1bKydyaQEoUnN09DxAUgw2SmpdrRCAj/p9Rc/2JhnL550tv/ik5FkbODrMb6@On@I5mOlcGtj49adO/l8VlVVZn7yxSc/v7e3l7@bLTxpFnbygryx/ed/trGhqtuqtNH2PKWdbJ6efsircp4X/@J7yc6TJ1/wvEbuv3/8qqHgowSPM1IiFbxyRAEjPstwK6RQIG97JV4mFLgSM/rrJEL3iw2iNHZK//Obj18k/ERDlT5w4e0nXiSK5QQzggFsudB2lmgktjFYcZ6YSfV6HYyl//kfIX7jPYCDPrNteDQKIaziLNEQ6jTKZaJRBIOiqpDu//Pxx7EcAj8DVlKnLTK8doEhNpt8vqTyO224tui1zeH5OYIsSWE42x/6hkOU8m3lNlpMsMDLhhcOc7QS@FHDx7tEfHaUgT4hI77f2JDubgtwiWNJUdSWotwG9ivc2qrXBehXaLPN5Qq38WzDNO0NB47vEOP2B0tX4oN/kmslmNoH/5TXEdk3dcN1slyiuLH7/G6jAeXNNXJbjQy9gkZG21upzDvOLvCak@HENR38OmLtAX7no8HLZZXPZrO7Rx2IQqZTRKEwnYodBEHYR5YT7BI7hLlgcw4cGS3C1UBO0CaRO4sVWhfhyPNkE9pI@/n6cIkDvP7yP//lt//ym/T3bXr/Vzx8yO6ZfWkLAp1Bc2nAtVut6o0G33D5ixbaG0BjcrVcLUudeSu11Wy0j0CsffcyWcglybE1y3aw2ZBWutWk8Rs02UaQPNobiYVzg7k04m6BBwtMHeAdYIokwnLGyhVhjZAr4bhEuFJGaJ412gIOttWFplIstAUWq7kLlcOrpQrfaSeEzRlwIrXdUAvqY7LbYBcZbnrEwdzk1GJYkCC/jUXZFj4LWyPulGiE0RqLMJ81XJCnCpdoNqW2QfuKRpjR3Y3qRrlarKpSp7H@qi1i4EWDGobxxEucJaKrRgI6DPGZiCgz5vYsXhNRtZCQgMlS3DeEg7oCpjGdBv81F62uXFHha4FJ7fCkBvSh5gR10OFlBVrbbicS3nfg2oAf/cMVWfG5QV0CZxrk@rVBqsqWmpMKt4oHKna9Vy9XaDYylDMK7UZGRA4piFfCcNCXEL3b7b7UuyCZaFpX0zXF1ybaVJtpfnfSnXZ9faLjR2/JExTvOgEa3JxTcMpOiBVRSOQKymbiNpYtp1bw@7Ggm5TLuYqaKym5UjFXktVyIVeu5Er5XKkEAHMlNVep5FU1VyzliuVcsZgrVvAbvRCmCGFyCKFUyFVyXOJVc4McMf42JZnwamXeeD0VKUfDixocvAXBmSZAcAJFPcsl/hmuhqIqZAs6RxkeIBFSI1HpD0q4r5kTL8uRBAh7F@1XW81XWyReW0KQZ3iJnd12RpjPm2Cu1YL/diMy1ujFTFDU9jyT2X7WABnoWaOZAZDPApCiQChQsdMg7W3qFaUWJBf4b7dJewDembE3QJoRaC5eQC4y283turNPb5E2T6ENyWwvZX13l9LaLsRqbAIbSGcym4Kw0QTYzaCHgsBIkUEZAVKbpECAubj4GW@SzDvJorO7vQ28Zr49b8yb2/P59jb8t@lzHrzBdb597U9fi2tNmIV/G/lUqyk1WlIr4FVtsItSA11EqQWGBrwhXDOnltvYO6L0I7b/Zf7F7OIZuWCW2yLkmktska0EHtSTS2xxieevP/3f8G69/vQPUZIl8DOqXOKCEC4hbVUIdaOvCohzD23ykF02mPEOreiCDo2H6Gizh436sSQ9F0lVoEpySikX0yJ2/x2n38GdkCJ5DkEh2MHAgEYU8l7Cq@Ui38koM5UktvliibLbn7t2JZPJf/VcrZSSTAfHrXzPPc97GMvlIp8QuKbKiqBcNtj5q@yA7J9bdf2rn1t3cYnLCkEcpQjDC5cAMkpIEuiOXKKxPcJ1ZfhxCQG/EnZW/1B4uifsO6Ox5lMlHUfwQFSoHx7UK5UGKk/G5hPadrbubsFTgf/BBhSCtPoQtNWv6yMQzFv9XEFtoa76rgY6OzA6ofsCfw9e4o@c6Pg7eoE/cvISf0c@/sjDLv5OXuBvr4u/kxH@7rzA38OX@Hs6wF/rc7mcUuM3tbPetAf/6cvN6eYFxVVGqSjzzSlPcVaDDq/R@pzvzqrGmWaleHVH5dM1VsW5fCUN2ubn2MhKNfh2Aq77M3S/ptUrtW5dZWFZ75mynchfNL3FR@nYBtCqmsZxjVyl4LiCRkwPHuCQyVUUx03@5BuffJKs15NCkp4gngc3oYuBujQQWCFmPk3zQz8jVCNABp6XrO0mP9ekY1iFSruJnm3w4BJ1sqlsKrIl67LSVbpgMInsEnkoD5WeQtU72SDyTJ4ReeQoPTAZ8JPBZMp9Ig@IbMs2BANfMPkd2UdTH14D@PUBkAs/E5eydBVZJ5CQhbIs/bKP0sGY8mWHvDt0PD87bnFNkiT8cwP0dFERZbFotvGc9yb//HlL2mqrlTIRkezFTvN5K9nmWzyeAqpW8qQ7MzZaz3kQXmSeoRtdSMLzQPmvJaRWSwqqQc3Tap3PO52DR3c7HQl70RYxGpndDPQAu7t16BGC106iUdtpVWknE3Y0CWl7p9XICWguZqC7UMGN3Dcsw85Kmc94LQDDu7FBEdB@fv4cdKXUOWpM52fwOg8NH7Tg0WG6FPWWzj9oxazUABeGlaQPVkBYMkCubRe0C7IQEeEPSuc/19/8l/V/@JSkSarZTqcu5tspeqXxl05fzC/mwbORTqUCS2obfugAdoxyMW@gkQa6AFMzlW6n53PmBs9UepsBbEAy2w0adxEOup1ElCRNlj1S/7RvSDq4Wskaec5vb7v6ZatGuUFerpAE/7xGtMWERKs1lYFzdMMjigWbbGqXdPQ2XdPx@1@b3abS/vPv0WOod9I0UCFfqylbhFnUvFqr5UNbqVyrlUPLZipVuX415B2lCCpWPp9O12pg2QnBymCFuE3yKkPqpAXP9u3bLJGyenkZwszlixkZJ4JqtTClAiRreJrOeDiIq4eP6RHOwC0KCYJMgQRj2SmZngGPvD3JV/nbt1PBVz539tK3b6sV@fIychmPwUlZcup0eqbb6aB77vKS7/B0EqFSALtcvrxU5EpGSZK046Ye4acaIa2UoJBbaoMmWwGereZLafwaN81BYXu7mG80inlwKZYhIhSKcWxg5nyyxicuaDGUconxMb6GziQBDRr6Ue9inqA1SfKFdAp4YBrkzHkCfy6yS9ZrFQrpWl6WExdzngVWKhUWOk3yxVQ5Uwl@9Y00aYAQxX4oCeYy@a3S1i4I2vjzpqsu5Ki1C6OuzOsXRhU/ADKv6cGH8HBTqXH7dq4CqCnLCXJ3glvbsy0uYMd16JhQHoNHi0smM@TWbQ533LrJam2X1qxSLpBEssYchSSwdVIGHEvqVkEpI044s49bxUGo4BTa6W6QDU6lb3xwFdYVb6AjqMhx3kf/XA8u0iNdMsCLDFBFJSax6EUswvzpU9ejQA67At/ISuPiFbkY0cVG5nOFHKPSJHkw0U0cHXvyYG//4CSrbgskod7b28@qx0/vJBS0FhZ26p1D@9HB3t3HTyHCkwcHe8cH7x6@f/D0Cbh75HxxRb1E2FdEfUbMtMJ@Tj7gPnJfaoahGRPD6JxPJucvyEem2TGhaq0JlM0ZuMQzOlCksbYoXg1u3fS0jz7S3DG9yOvvfvn1d3/h9e9@4/Xvfvn17377J59@@8twfx/ub7D3N/6oUsDnTz791d9//Tu/C47/Fe4/hfsHP/n0Nz5mN7X/EO7/FnP7YXDHwrGbA1hf@8mn3/zeTz79@m/C/dvB/ZvX71/5wer7219af2O8b/7@zWG@8R/h/gMGKwz7jd9hbvi@Fv53WLiv/@brX/9P7P/nwQ@Nv/v613@Ij8Dyy7/55//t9Sf/RVXLf/7vX3/pm6@/9MnrL3319Zf@tfr6N/69Iscfv//623/813/yB3/9J/@G/r9Pn3/wNv/Xv/nLf/W//9X/8Vd/Etw/gPs/gekHf/VfoLn@3R9/F//f/OO/@9Pv4v9//b2/@@Nv/d3X/h01/BYz/MNv/xF7/uiTL//oS7/2o08@XfP88o3PT9/C/dN/Bpe3z@fbwHmbcn1Wl09/pvz8Y7CxSAVoACj3F1//xleAeH@dkNdf/j4uZId7zf/7qkLDfJ/Z/n9gUK@XGX1kMMH9rddf/gai6H8BFME/wtdXI8uSD7N8dWEBtH5nRaRf/Mmnv/Y9aksY1QadmcJeuqyWM1ug0GxVKkFPHUxaQZSvLEOLAAQpfRW5z5LfV5Fvvf7ux6@/969ff/e3Xn/3a9g/C/lKdi8rKG@Y8YOAhbcIhwGLbxMOA34I6XcydNBOyHwIto0PC@Wcbdu1Dz/8kOtcSrhjYveSfAg/8mF4EeaFOyoCr9AP3XGLBQH35vPnbZwmjrlJCgMuqewdeOECIEhJUG9ldiRFZV7GpbTJYpEaOOTKuVYs61K/v1WFH4FHtbp1kRV2WiDk0ahzzgiLpARQNySiaNncVk6DgFKehSNVe1fOZ0pbmgaaawbhZqiYsxUKX4UcmWaCJKfBVDK6Q6DpFjVOCZsNmFLvKTelM87wLxFSJjlCbPavcSRDJSJ64Wd7QiM1BPHC2Wpq5AqQTGYx10ClQcIEsS3mQufgabp50D7oBF5mCto2GHCAHLzugLBfr2cwYp1lEaysMI0yoVnJZOpQbozN4mQ7ZQQxvUOhQMw6RUF9yiJmEF4jREeGQyeam0y5fhcSrE/vokMGgVOwz5/XG@X6tIHgXjHsZKaZOzRPCKyemTZegb1OYUI8LnH3FWSlXM9kGmVMEAvJqgcVbKykAi0cLTtOALM6gDeuwtrZJeQWr5R5Ns2ygQhjofGZWYTGgBjl6DmvqPxzPq/KPARuZbaCstF/aKT3FsX@Bk03SJKVHVPeoMBI5/nW8yAgDQmpCYIoigRuXPGwQ3bJDsewlsnQzMArEyCR0gmli8iBUExxGVrrDG0AH5zpdw2JquZroG/UCDq5OoefQaLLaGRuc4pLpC5IIBvLwbf95pwGYfJyjru41IIlVJsamYNTkcMQNM361me@MLOItc3NTS7R4HP8YzppnJEk4p5W6UI4aM9Uc6oSvljh0dmgqwIZFh/iQu0sR801LCZ5/fH3Enm5lOA2k/Q7qoQlRG5l2L27u0VuAVrpO@Y2pevNhEzOyTsJhsbtTIZXIdGGA7YtisIMhcY9I4k6/sE9QcmNJMgTzTW9LJeljDILL7GeQG/y@PHjIL/U4Vmdy0A7VHMK2nHCcDKZQHSjh5Pz2awoZsVsNniL9E0dxMAgUt/gLW4i6klcw1NKZfyAoq0PES/cq1evgDY4xEX1EIdCqZHU1XyZehJKBlNcCaaNshzbUG5Zs3DBqZqvcGx8gijFPCEpShFwpQmurEwBjac5tjyLkVd4pZJqGZRoDAk1JqYgGANTVJBTsSWsdOsIKZSWrJCzuBVHHdnYN64aiNaOsvylyoV06Ln/mOw/fvjw4NHJuN0mnEE/2Gl0xq6jG56XQr@9R3cZ@aqVYjrRbGLZT6oqck7uoCojGWcO7x4dHlcJw1hQdSlajhqdcA/wUlG4xHj8wXbCxfF31@Dx@zQOf4zP6gIVKbUCXD2daHAJ3UA1DOgU/3DXyJExQPJ96A3uOFOSkrM8n1WKqCSncf4YsvPzzoTg@XNs0ztwB1zmJ0J5MeeNCyE2A4UODXKkcswgKNRAcpVyaCgxg1IqYoDH7ENOOa5xfHACkE8eE0WVRXLkdE3IVONDMhUJAR5w5IwMJyvMaWzkSCfmyMEQVt0y7IE/3MSPY/ItmY8haLMpZ/Gn5nLwVPLFrFIotTc2rAsB4bQoyVzgIsY5WC8ExMk7cBHuHY68A05wCXPCOWPDJsHg/uHjGiNe3E5JUpD7Y9/llQLwhTSHcxYBPG4cv2qAdGhny5N/XGLji1/0SaNx8OiucHgPhyKmQxKugBTMnjgUKeH0Jq5BfQeE9Mz3TVzpLfZMb2xpM2jEgK@tBiDEx5nZxHw@7wPMw3tEbajUyuL28DnXqUsXzPOpxhFg0H0ucTscfeFKt6vV@islX4K8VauvcqrKgQO3BbKG2d8AaqOrWbYk9uPtel6RM0owG2KTNM/zNQ8ylcuVpS0uofA8vHK5HEcbEOGqBkfoGqdXcr0uBDw@r9AlThweyq1N62p0BWGntxZhczILiz7gQQa@S@TQr8T8AlvYLUBRcNEv/UpjLeAo8u3bORyDyuXlqOyEoobMoUo3c/kcVhK4gWs7kS8F02hQvnaCswyf9OpgTrSwwKwxKwmeoA35X64sc4lmApo212w36//f/9pNrj39l/sHtDSbdW4KHDJ@B84Yhr7J0o/jHjqPF//Hj0dx643/0WPn4WNn5MAfesKHyMBri3@ttmS9@R9wTmSeNRCQOd@YAjnBLy8XwPoP3/7473/9P//9v/2qiFdgixz@4dvfYu6//av4/Na3//5bv/D33/q31OVX/v63/03g9Q@//XvkLrTx2UsN@k8OP0/@6R/h18o/@Q5@sBys8f@n/yHw@uRbC0f8nPl3rv2/Rf7mV/7Pv/3OV//6Bx//7bd@8Le/9cc/@vjraln50ce/9Le/9YO//tOvEbD/@Idf@dHHX/ubX/rkRx//IoSL/3/8w6@GXl@KHMEMLtf/4A5wuX8xF3I6nOinc9fbwXF/Dbr4vKlU8u0DYBZN0t4OTwJsQOhtL/hIOXCPOo9VLfkmc@MbnmH1RVzSXee3x42crPLbwXHCDfK@YSMzDuI3evWeo9NPA9d6oomfaMY9PSxePs/XHBsP/apH08Eklb4Y1M/pXt2aUR@IeLyEa2sWRO86vZno@TMQtXTHctx6EpTRJEir75uORekFzHs9x0ZJ0K4boKzgEPxOLpevQvnEsTPeUQslgQhNRQbxDW@lnO1Bh@LuQD9WVbMbxk6pVO2JumVo7k6hWkBvPZrW3ynI1YH44cMH931/fASSh@H5O/kKRMAjmvAwlZ1ytVCANszzmSZNsY3fPGUdtbCxAR2bofUEeOOsvyeo5XaVpl@vJ5M7OUUVlGpOLnNBYRcIs2u2kFeKO3LVj6ORHFim7bhZnsNPM0a1gBU4VBp5Ob8twRsUcAmXIIBY0iB7xsBA@YHWnLItjZEmwAhBNTB2wVjYlrpgNMFY2ZZMME4aOUXeliZg1Bt5BVx1RiVYG8Ts1SFNLFkGs51FcskOlYugo67ajm3MuWpWy5oXtOaq/X5/vnWRWVg47UJgNqjTuaBluxeRtSbEwlXJJCuYC09w0fpAIhfBiosqrxbKfK1ZW9hLRb7WnnO7I6NnavhZ3ZZ8cT1WEQQoBjUBCbUIN6@6juNXu0bfcY1FwJxSDAOyDF0PkOfnUXItGVO8uJ5cMRZoerHAXoS1ruXop0FK9Ptyq9LKF/g5pwfocI3enCWUrWZDRxaVEgdWFlZb4tkzLrF19H6u0QDqvMiX1HwhX1BzxWKhpIKwWMkXC2UgDrkoF1QVWES@Uq6U5tA2JelVgn6giuxfhG22So8oT2lVdnBfs03Srx6Z1kU5JzAmk0rXQLpIvOISt47eVxuN9WNcKRC831eFRj1XqIAphyY1R2URVRXUnJBTBCWH/zcYVPy/fXgV/io@IVZO5U7wWJNHIPOCuG@TB3gyg@@QE8ehm4fuGPqaEPtDjR6hsu86nvePCHNHs0@Z112TnaEZed3X8ENO3sj0h2tCPB2PTNvDHUj/XBAORl3IIPJ0FuAOPFzLcVYFKJGnT@BxdPju/ZPovbrUD6NTqQE57FhqiHFysLd/nyuSO48f3b3yKgTgCuTBwb2TyFpivmHUQgTi5w8ePLhqDV75x0@P@hPHxZu79/hpfvGInHDPFZeHazlQ5EyBBA@0osiEkj3ZABU7NCgcbve6na@Q24GxUFwYZTR@wDaUmV60I4ztSaxyJ@EuM40go@8aBD98Y/ToSCY9pC0YBVBKFY4bE9s5JyWZ9BzL0vA70/0NcBxqHukaBiq1Fv1MOiZ97rhW79zsGRsgakIaFQW/6YuZ4O4DkNFEH2ICoFTg0Z49/AI0zul3rYlBJvj19TWO8EInNLrmYAjyxLkTBuC6mkbg/qwXxDfil3@zg8/SoG7XfKzrwbkEt/cYRysqCZ7f5/n7mq/VXKP0jDRQUBpmy9kc7xf4Ac79Wp7fa25NQDfa2MiXidqS92W6NGqm1RWp1q0TpXjZ2Mk7u6g5oSq@1TES5UG96hWKyg72wXU5s5twvPtGucbzmp0FlpmtejgKcY9@YPvANp@RqdjBwdRWzcZhDLobd18D0btapWRW/ZvvfP/Hf/YtlPTIXcfVNVyojLoroZpooMKKdORErZQL5UpOLWfLlXK@oBQLhayiZpVSuVSB/MlKWSmWCxUlW85XQETLV8C3UCkFCrAkbZE9Cwe8skzJlbaqAN7W8du223QQRhw2uARbJEJeprQ0SWiRfUJ4A@LwZM8eGBbAwLEzn@5y3DLr0HUTRSa5EgHIGtFJ4t69ffnePZ6/gxZcOrcv83wPLYWyLJfu8LxBffbLKIXyDotTxgPbeJ9ZZPkO1OKEAcAzynl@iJaDIk6J8LyJlv29e/cwnT5aVIwPwU6ZD7NYoaUEwWy0gEZOAbyIoEGwPZZOnmb0AC2YJPrcYz774Mfz74bZQZ8jFowBuB@WdG@P5w@ZZW8PffZpsQsso59Hyx69eN4FCzQxnh@AYeBC4@b5LhixofG8DiZ9poEbfk8Yj7e2fY3nZww9iCCen9LQmn7K853QHZN5P8hNAbFbpRaFlXqXWir443k1zDQGy0WWHM/nI0seynb//vva0O8ZA3bNXPbWoaT37@c0czo5uNd9993uYNB1Z3sH7x6h1/7@fRBqZhO3O@gGEbsduByItX9f1U5Hs6sXlPqw06lq1kqvz3c6ec2@4tWZdQzMIcR6ATkLrgEmNOrsg9f@/c6utmrRDwXYQR4zgncXrzsjeN/RuswrvKgXfU@7Xb4GzQAUllaKQx0L1@1g8zwFnm1nR5ruOjW0T@tEpuulZ82i3K5RDzICJUmuzdG/n8KnhuPT6YtZc1qX2/VpvRQsve2n@NZULZh8dmO0o1QK1Q1tR1HzmWkVN2g7/SRJCsoOSSm3t16S1KP0jgqq0gbf2tkR@KbS3imWniFzq@JjR1XK1byskjSz5kpViCMnZULwkW6W2julQnURuVTKaJJaLZVA/AP8@CBEdHFEuENSqXNDO02nMet0SBHKQwtOZrTQZq2fmmandZZJMkvXpnWlxs6EJfIVaKlUDw8an@h4IAVhQAcAcAq6Ei4YS/FKpcxDHiQplQZmNJ/PGXIu8nJ5fnHhXVy05hGrlMC0GNT94AsnpycnHwK3AqlklqWCaCMYDn3CvuddC6zv3t8XDx@HNjxDXLyHArLjivvI45Z8mKQcOp2AuiTeh64dVOXQDeL4rmOJB3R9NUjZoUd4kIcYnPMpntxfgnM8dM5ZyhDJq6Egp@HWeDxi3ewRrd4Ak9YjKZoroqXPqVDRaTTqnfrIGI39GRQxjPV5Qs8fX4A59Fje6Scf8IPYNPpF33VGgUenLs@h45smpoJA9kDGm7hZgNipE0F5PnJ6z9WMXuvhGet36ncQTK0D7y4o@4brOi4Puipf6@/Y9YntaX3jieHifv/Dx5sg7OBxGak@MdKbpHWAofdRt5oLDZfYizw@moxSmtDoppedcAohckA0pb4QFv8Ch9Ah5zw/r/XrJPUMgr4Au7tJUj3xTnonXwOM3SGdNDjJz/vP@0QlxXyNqkIphAVNkGIKMaCl643Pg4zGQJ9CJw25Car8FKBiYgAYaoP6aOmxOa/pdYukBDJNUxzla4N6E6Nf4mNbAAFDEJqXbZwB@AD1gxcT6Dwb0Nxrs4RW9yZd@tUNIncVVS7WpuCmlPK1IdS39mxac@vjiWvULLAGcwaEllirAW4BhQDm5WXq9Vc@Tm8LhTpzq1FQlyi3dMROfVqz8bxEoJR6rg4emWZezhbKINIUSlkQIdRiVilmc9l8ViihK8gP2UIWHEEVA@EoZaV4QvisPJVFJasYSjYlPzd7z9PZ0xSKMRR56azvHNiTERVsoMqQWqkd3lo6o24BinoO0bYFSrzAZGpYLsD9kIzN7JBCOjI0i0VICyS3lbI2Uxho82QyPmi2q9WD6fgL4JUSXuwUMyU58zKdrqU20nXPeEHnV@6YQCAaIBc5Ey3@eANoOphXId5k1IRaB5NSUqvNZhfLWpKzOTkHxTQ7l4NtvsG3s/JGUYE6m9NxdIUwzhKfSgDJiVu4jTuoK1gG1KFSUWuciCP4CXLHndC5jVxZFSpSYasgs/kEBoIbBywScUtSrXB3RjKVTJbUZHKhWKeTNZy43eAXM2lU3aZLalNJYNkkeVstFHd4EAD5Kl9ReQi24LiYSyKHOd8i@5rhaS7OuXA4XEHyoK5fcPOL@XaDm4rcwci0TC1LbFPHz1eZ@qnIoTSbJV1zQPqaj21Z5PagtIdVkTsGXc@gpuYBHmFOWHx60gVGawcAq3Q@yh/OQP51If6MTs/54nVXqCWC7zCp5RDkc9wxHpSwrT7DX@nZw73H@Lu3m8B9EGT3c@BXAffys4dPHz99fI9uhl/sVv0s1y5HJLrZAUT4WqJGx9FxJQMkw@T7t792cb6aSBu435tkREFs0JMEdlkqreBMG2mDkM@6GyOz3XjG3i3c7gegOXp@cpO06Sppw0RVnbyvgUC5Q5JQ5Zo7aqpqrt1USyCWQNfVlFlQVVVqkItOgm5ebQB9Ty8g09uZBp4X8Hkym2kZISz6bdIYZDZldZY46/DFSo5ubu80FPmUbCRvb@GHgQWSODvdaKhbmeSTai6TvJvM5RNnqdZmI6PMkhLZyqizPq75wrVDUhLCqcbWrdxW8mmmWh5kq0oGnyo8q0kibCR2O9nddMXjKCWTxBKCNyp79b3B0V4wzUH29htldRacc5B41uHLpSCLrU1AmZp5trsUvwGy0DOc7LxSb@RnuHZxEXiylkxcJEkiOU/Om8k2l9ilJzKo7EQGkojOZMCVW8E6gVy@SNIJkg5spUrCS6Xpuolgov5zyd1EEufDiee9AqKmdUGbdri//fPPVWA0CdsJHZyJj2O6IEoVCjjbm5Cej70vquXcw8PH9l33nsElWhuXGw7O5JMaz0Dy5JX93hcIGUONJUmrnpjW88F8qdJoCMq2iidZlUgVhIC@UhTkywbjZg3qUVTB5/VXfjM/3S6DXZUVsKtqIaM2GsoWiKGJ8etP/9B3Z@Ti4P29BySJs68//rPvqaUf/9nv0WXlyTmdkVVzpQSERKNSLCUuLsYXFyAEzplfIdFOXFtq1wY0SYpWKW2JQAtSWQNDR0oE29lSSklJJzwhEWwqKBaEVEqR1PRWriynwecyOC0opcplsIbLIqgTXyzw6cTBkVlQld3tHSjZTi6v1jagWpXooA0S/bYNr5LgEuWHzy8JAYve6A0GpkpNkhS0o1cC2X4lbMMbaviVsEGe1xu4XlDBMzrCSfYt3OmPS16SjYy0lSSga5NGc16btzN0op6OfjzbsltXkNHawK2hy05bNvyMLY/@DINaqYMH1tBmbH3k8amttCT1erTfwUUSgtBIsFbXMUihAfSyJUEut8KJdfYThFb69Vd@Q1WLP/6zX7nsXHY@VFW1UqkUFTXx059uT@yJZ/QaP4WIT8Jz2YCIdLOHxHrinBq2J0ZjDrSzM238hJFpR2MVhJ0iZwaxIoOo81xiYqM@xsKHIxc4RkFAJjUHttGjIxbcGUrUtFo77CS0XooG2yKgkGSpPkePXkrXOC7UdZi@5g70LIVBtvDE2WY7zV1w76AXyGcEdL4a984CFDiMQCJz9I5nTdwx3VKbovGUdpbchiiQwjt4ytwGhE6ToN8WgBNDX30tKsuyR7FGZW6ChyPjmXUgjnDvQJTghGxrRsaa6xk0pGmDrCBiEJpP6tFrQtptSNtiETrUNUVLzwJkCcsdi2SDGse9A/IlxYIJYicxtyFADXjKO4AAKEMqAGy2yTbJpcmFmcnUFgfizfEgFNxKqoUntnEYDaH1AE1R5BqGAydQH/EzoEgXQQ0D34s5hkAYDLbmrQ4KKEanNhToTSCH6VuDAljnQ6whWjRy@/YiV/W62UsTWiKEf2qOccyW1oO9Oq8ALNTkbwFLBZEqk8HKfmeZ7ADjGZpdoDqBnTFYi0UlPFrnHAf/tyZapMgrVUU9aliAoL5Yq9ABZRAZ0c7qUCfbdaKopTSJMq9D3nWaKXqeTzQ80ZreEtUPQ8855PCnifCLPsCsTuLj4AHd3jWsy9FlhHCPgBI2oadc@kONMYPga94gs0B0ZHqHfhg7igVFMS0aum@6oArTpXXhQXepnJLGaIuDAWk@6LY5NU9w81ohjS8aC0MTeGt48FqQzgYVX3UHKtQbOzY9qc1H1oTbB4EigEdBAo8c32DZntjn@JmtoG5o5HiOoJSg6SDlY47pyXP02900Lq5R67qGdhriJkuMgUj0UY@oFZKihGbjcg07ApemkWiGu6BBIY67ljGCLB0bBt3Z7lUlaQCC36SLM@DSQxPoanjPhO7H9qTgM@nSuXlqSid4pLLg9HEDPAUOUEBWxObHVrmBsjmxesRynFNimacGm95IxU@9wy8XFLOg/GQBs4sbEFtFsVfNZXEgTMmyUHCX4FVixnI2FncjNUtff@eUjVQHa/SS9mCmi59AP9PsGH7pdckFgynezOPoIX91gspDCuxixHKhZbLzspJ4YFYyLQLue6k0R@vXgygYU8Rps3GKT/Bp0Rtbpk@N3Ng1zggOhnDYxwDT1DtBFrAVQ2nfoR0AbXvQsvDgPd@tQs1lICduL6VD0wsYvE1ukZzKYUBIGYOyDAAMrPr6MnTwg6hYDs/vQcWIdK4I@Qq0zlEP/PBgr4D8MH5I3WimxyAuyJtsBOCw06Fp1QlrFqGlELNg60B6pkXfAM8i5HBFTjZSfAbAZvg0z0BH8a9GZ9TOUV5SJdchZQlCCFANUKiooCHLwYNmY9/JwiUjdzTgzngUOlI9EP35@blIz5icuKZoePjtKM@xNUsaD0wQhx3JN0bj4Ou6Jn4wPYC7MAns03DieDjemaJQW6/cnrE3x/W9erBoNZXse0nsHM/w00iD0RnqV5DhvkcJ6p5JP5@mp4I1tIz@1Hb2IqS/KtKfUE7OEQghCGaanWX1LADLdvXTbP@8Vws8zmiDBOBQi0boiCe/uqFl5IUmc9yPQjg@8tHIq2ud0nUFAIlnMwaLpFkJw5Cz0BrYxyaudbeNc7LnutosRf3TGBoJODWjYg@ZQbdPfcAI3Qy5YMeQmtPmrL0UfRpFh04tWj8EjDyFPdeNQNmZtOg/Zf5T8J8y/@ki0TDZ5rTNRDJ0mmNxkOpx0X4YEsHMwjBzdn7rwodCBjmcKAwEhpwtueHiXr1OY4f4Zjaox3pIGEATY0C4kZKaz1rNVtv2jPOtdkYaALHzFBFQ4wC62aY4Pe9FZsS@dWaNHW/JCboPKt4E@UYnfRhQA6MVLGNUQZQwGL5MPHNzMArWNTGBICgwQEA5DDxRNNjzU2a6Fh2CTD2BcJr8AscsY80gM20qfQVegRuISwz1DLFxQO0YIHSPigTZBB8Sthz2pcCQO3zgOhAmDCvQj5sBi5yRZDsJmLzSVBivqdFKiuVKEMJsAtpRXK1fLUroD1XRvOIVK@Y8qP949jc@c/b70C5W554SLOswaly8qeAKfRAhguZCsUoa9Vi9Qg6kLc0yXOi5Dph8GvTWkMyWFKoZLB0sgndu@vowFat8Pc3qhx6fwNt8NSKFWb0ORZzVWbNk7SJEKUN4FM0Los1CQgjiMwYCMOSV0Ywg2v/b3reup40si/6OnqKDkwHZ4ubYTgZfZmHACWs5JhtwMjnYw5JBYGYAMQjbMBnvbz/EeY/zKvs1zlOcU5duqSWETZK57LW@2WtPLKTu6urq6u6q6qrquV5tfnjIC4eYr6h2pyE5JyTnXIVLz1cgeSmrgfZUVdsLDs8lSKcYO5AAeHneRkEMmiSEZ9866Mnx481oglqVajNYc4gLJA@hiI181rmMbb2lIa0tWhEAyIhLALp8iXDBiC54@bT/y1@jmJRqjeJfkg14rQAGoyV432AdyGcy0oFB4E9s0T4Aczex1TISeToqwP/l@L@EpV6q//LLL3Phkvnwy5wV@d/v8vISKatNUE36yOd2cEE2AkuFbrJ464I2GNghNKcJ7RUeFoXfwQIwpmKswY0QSooUtwfNC2Rf4CnO7IEfSYoKVk5YoqQ@xguNlTj3KHczNSIog9cd6BkX44S5r6WPV1aGYGMU4qR6WhGbFCbSI8FZCc2JaYKlFEbj6WD8EAJ0ukeSN04islo89wrwH@BgKZBAJrJfpIg25qO4EUWubnotSsMkJwLxqUjldWwQwR4ox2M8XrcSzz2RsL6BiiYybqV2YhrhPOzymCRUH5DzJuMU1LIS6UyCqsI7WFrxnRkGwaOJ7xXCgDLKpkoRQ4UC78fK0L0gzhy6Mu47pJjZ2fyr3N63BvVubM2sUevbS2uzc5gQsATZ45F3M73r/tR3r297YigmP17NO4tffhZidwdDXsX2Nxy8mN87zFKw1UuB0bDf5iiDvkTwOwrPxAzYGWXSTgrKnc8RAU8F5fEX5KtQQJkwwqVic6S4EI0Ks8NRa@/ycAyL8Kg1vtxHs8Zs63C2ld9K4Ytv8iZm6sGaqU5rdgl0uddm0abx2gatBq/sE8Urjw4/YU8zQuaCGeyQHp7C0uEF3uMyHICgT8x0RwqpjKwDZQUYNoCo36NrVHuo2VN5C5@keg@VMqKGkO8GKJT4Hzy89cujHRaPWGeYEB5A4nEXSBiUjx122RfbrLQ7AnuEpWDX7utI4IijOQanv5/lPWPIjPcGd5X6gsYxvHJVoOKKp/6wUxcM4z9uBp2fSq/Fdi73Mp97kddIhvdsIoK5zIudYLsCIqkP2@jms5vfMYySO1mw6x5s5ghrJ40ALXGKyvF70MucW2c8dozicMg@fh5eTOBMb51uxjDqTpfcR69uiCKoxt0guUCrdW@mHc5mTxd1L5Av8KoNyn8Pkx//om/iCFSdnrxYzDLQCgIK2WgwY1uJezvAWyN8y0/PHQ7dOyRYB40uTA@sNHJgjzM2TRFGCYmlcCF9f3TjzXBKo9UYAdpXeA1mxyfDGDa/DowMmTCMIYAiw53W2LgbwQTa6wxtVLUycQhAQxoFFALQte5Nx3kQB4OQ@EwchOyYCsyw1chk3anh0lwZ2aja0oXzisA0KlRNwx0GuPmm2hCN2knzQ7FeEfD8rl57Xy1XyuL4o2i@qYhS7d1HcswVb2qn5Uq9ITAMtFQ7a9arx@fNGrxIFBtQM0EfjOLZR1H5/l290miIWl1U3747rQI0AF8vnjWrlYYlqmel0/Ny9ey1JQCCOKs1xWn1bbUJxZo1i1pV1YygnqidiLeVeukN/CweV0@rzY/U4km1eYaNnUBrRfGuWG9WS@enxbp4d15/V2tUBHbMKFcbpdNi9W2lnIH2oU1ReV85a4rGm@LpaaSjtQ9nlToiH@rlcQWwLB7D9ogtUT/L1Xql1MQOBU8lIB4geGqJxrtKqYoPle8r0J1i/aMlgTYq/3EOheCjKBffFl9D54zUI1SBcSmd1yt4EoWUaJwfN5rV5nmzIl7XamWidaNSf18tVRr7wjitNYhg542KBW00i9Q0wABqwXd4Pj5vVIlu1bNmpV4/f9es1s5MGOQPFbzUo1SEqmUicO2MewtEqtU/IlSkAw2AJT68qcD7OtKUqFVEKjSAaqWmXgwaBCI29W6Ks8rr0@rrylmpgp9rCOZDtVExYcCqDSwAMLHdD0Vo9Jx6jeMEePEjMKuhONei4RTVE1Esv68i5rI0cECjKrmFyFZ6I2meQQdbTUAb4FVujj3Shbbe8qtbB53ClqW9ePnPP38q1coVkVDnhongwznsOq8iB1P6N9hp/I/wM3QA0HWubvptvFEFJXa/GgtVI69vYRYEE@OvL4wHzqql7EYVNjba7ffFdrH@utFum9Y6NUNoPFaDEnyCsPZAKVP2ESPL0IaGQmWhwHQ/CBHq6BsUB3vO1BLsiEwlmfrf0OaKt7qbIpvtOrIamkIQsBJLYQ@euiMBwLq4NJIVFiPGgyZJ6qHfA8kOVDGlwGc6bXiNPedCrgf/jH8NfvDmoL2A1ZlF6Wy278wYDVBQVTPcCBmY6B9p3wHtiyR5z3F@6qdyenPOuGtm8Poh9JCUdajszBkO@ynzkepXTj9SPR2tT8iiUVNlxvU4wIC1C2RMPgeTJBNyXDJT6lkK/2nP6I@psGELGhpKqCkywUuFKPUNV2/lLpGsbCgEiZoHGWW@t8Xvqx9Qyc1t7@xH3r/x3/PcQqdB9C@FDa9F9S7pz5tLLgATjCybQJKBtDdms1odEMtIoPQL30HBayzE1yfhXn3t0L4OJAFB9sYe6m3ibjwdzHXsYR1@XS@@PT4/OYGlE7HdebX7cm/f8A8xv7f470dshzw86Qx3Avs4yGn0SZslJRB8aKZo7vgB@xMDZ7NYEAM61KDRS7Sa@XcUsZDAeSNIljrA7nqYPmGMZpCEM6Z7lcic@dRQ/Bo7MyUDpEJdNbE3I3tOIr4NshLxgDw0xfvQYdTm@A/C9qe/muJ@hyQDSRYjn1fgXOMJr3sJrEQnbT33ZszHIFgkk1B8zIfiPg3w0iWRL8hjRPoleVsbRRBscaBxvtKwU01A4mkUCyH1UPLuhibekdVWKpd0Fgtvvpf8Bo8fpbsAOQ/Y3qw4awAZT/yaqAMHiq7sdEtCvsQAOzyiVi0dCLQgmBIpmntSVfXNrNpsIFQwwhWtU2HA@75VNtokKsLJvyVB32ZORVMowtmXHCt/A@fGdUdC2VfWWPlb2fgEw/JNxky1O78NQxX56FsFFTlDZPoqehD8P5EmMfAPQOME6AG1NJeKtShJUJlWoL4SUQZ3yoihWU4CauqvPgZg7vWBufY7Ji1Dc3IlQBLI0VmoFx/JiaSXiiEAMrmJngXa/O26Dl1kDDszqE5/S5iyOtpgxp3RJCXkXqG2iiW46b1Li8QuS9lt8IcpTDLMCq3BU6gq/saK2xXNelCZIqq8eO4lGJyprKnZTTzPCCY8cSlSJK8me8BZOTnL1DogD660Dafrnz@BWHq/0iK4KTSHo9DaL61qilAA@gjxWe4nRRq6ojN0PSfiv8LJ/pvkU4De@5a8GU86AKCnAbo4IZznXSEvnXNmd7hBDBk6OT4E0ETqOfleYCN8LBEIDmq5NTNAWtpW73zs54T9nYb9@ZhjTOhnQagSGfYxkRiO8dZA4Bm681e8tReA8nC9bjOLZTcbriXuHIrkYbOErI@Blx3XnYLoaGO/AUdrsDAz4oM0Ojhj72YqvUFgPxtMpUVCCf3QzIyu7CZa4DbDsRuEmjcAuWGGNhfkD@rSyLHH0kFkME/viRQwr@LRI2RhcmuZb@VF6iD4cgA0IScvIuKB2MOkZFSKCSodsByi4MDzlQuYJS63cyBywfS7c6c/4d6PItC463R9Py8NJLxQg1Qdk8dMZ8Zdn7geWTRgKNAC4lMiz4a0K7vz0x1K3rBHv5TsBAI6vkoEvkboCUY9@fx2fCaVULGhgHFl68B8e2kYTKTStnS08l2v8tu7hEqcwnW/Uhkj36uwSVwkLsb@klKQV3s@V6IjPvG66T99xCe@2s05fO7h7IE3aD@XIigijDIr2myX1znCD88rPgycaVe3iYIk07UnaH4j1ccdEy8q06F0oujYM89ZgAbQyQ7mWYLRTv3dvR63S@7Q7g/cgQ16GoZXzHnFw8cFPeKA9afunUcxxZxzSCvUXQTPZA2Xh9r4W3rs4M/goNObOZOUfgQymy6KGEKLWgwd4@NZq79fEX9PoifOfp2d3aCSX0fe1n3jXYNuur@y7ot8XGU@LUAAcoE7ipzO0DG5gz6Ph6old5LSjjtUgauHCmg4Xom0sLXP9ysx/hZIRAe8IYwVMktHHnonUDNbiXGrO7e65NExdWewbpUdjFv1UvTasjENJqwi3@EpREHkX@W0qpRjsjtHrw58WKwm9/bLPxl7QOAr0M@/iOOWOEagJa4nZwOsyaRMSJ8twIXcmQe0RtNKDKvYoA@70DAEtD2PQg1/XqyiBp0qglAknRaWuBJnZAoUH0x9kWrDktNe0AXYSZE0yVEARZAiXduyimEdnVl1/xq9HTzi5jC7DC5MJQk5pSG9ilQdoBKm0AvBnNzoKLOH6uMzZnt73VGLEPBQEjCEg5ZbMpVQkgt6YvNlwzM61nKnsBgnItSTp5JJb@ZOkmtSb@XaEXvOHUfrjrmKSJ8izHYIm@Vml0h7uMDHxb4RxSfCNGGK0Sk28BCqr/Tss3mUiPPDNs63w/biETqsollwJutvKv54d3nu46Z4i6GlaqPxpxThji5f@/77Vhs63l69gkiYrF61acVo45LRXvCjBipCJp9K61OIuE/iHqFHFyiH7XaBdvr4rCRq9ABeOZCpTyGXIaQnusHbIwfXpUkvAx1Jmep8yl@kfIFzbi3oKC@fvkKXTfzAAFEqdtKBHYotuMFgRfiIYi16qTa6BeZxJYKnI/bZVZ5PElGfYBTjII077N7bai/S@ct9hjT3IYFWwbdwPwBJvsJirfacoCyRAqZ4DCn8Hi2tTdfr9@pr@wLlAALXps/eDR7BgzSFncFr3zvX8I/@qT1HGThoStYMzajwRGjT0gBzAbSU/tBhdRWlv8GUOR4eUnIagQLBr1P4Z0vWQOfovZxPbawy7y6wiCnJzbPNxKxoVCVgKP6N5JdTkUVdUlwBgCPvLoP5kQcI6CRG2OOhwNDpzUKcF0JUjhFUPMzjtISX5GMW@JDEfEeiygI7u1qJXFyJb3UY6VggIFjElwkQAZklvkgABTa6WFy0Ei/j@xOUAIFY8T5THIZCjkqYhv7IMQEpY17ODFaUVl5YOcnB9HFn1wx99Pmbvn6b077mol@BPj6GrXQ@@vVVLvQ11Oz2drhqqCbQw9RbDX0EUpg6wv6q8HX/Z5BLoOZAriTcA03JCEkZ0vcLMxqClgl6W@ZHTxygieNIyRgKHh3GpfOkKir1q80BayEX94fd2UWSjgzQE/6re6tiNhQmMvIieTEmR3s27rJCSBJrArd67BZquuRNgYYT8jgB/VbptG5PvG@enOhKsLhaKEejkTPdzeVyyMRXeiiB8ttCU9LAzYZLZ3s3w2F2cvf36furLK39mGN66LkFpUE7MCQwKbyMO@1znA3iAEWxdBoIPHJvHdT1b3o9PaAFTyhx8GDYuCT7inUFbUAD3@nlfZMD7E@CDfaf2EHs3z@FP/vubBY0JRR1DAW1gXoXtwl1egbkwRc99P3yT6oIGC7MypsJ9i3z8OgT7iAYJ0aDRc6gJpqFJPsn3jjDoWuJD5iV7GmCLCqRCicneoUcF8ETRiQKuhgNgcMs4dwOhsH5lIdFdF5HcGpjUlE7ysseIw3qTr8yn6QSrR8SsK1Al7ewm1vo7WuJRD9hStf7NcAyHwLaa5Ue2ZNUh@gULQxbvZzBwRNg9CJvxeo@oSIm2cQkzR4vjUSNRzfzozsYp6DrJskCKjKAhpd6sqK4T9zExTzfQxrmGIbEiW6CW6vG/f7XLY1ftyzeznq99VZFCqrggf2sFZHjyr5uQaQzAJqBcvoBPTG68h9pmNYnkUAoFnAw9Gl53cEKbaxgGM87hz/fpYrFong22doSxeIxPGCin@OiKOOL42NRxiwq@Pubw@3d3X1ec8vmJ3h5rF7ei2OAwZfOdq6nZfgJ3w4xwA22e9Iin2UPn1n7z9qHB0f7XrZVPL7MZvvwxPcuZYvyB17IlD2mH60f/EKZTCb7rPPp2Tf3@/i7Vb5MPrtqPZtcJvv7yGVAhuLNzK3O0nbgPpqZXhkbvAtob8mPVOnZHmZzlVWFSo8wsqc/wepSEBsdL7sh33och0tr7EbH0d47Y0yEAiq8CuGIqvIGhsiP7AWa42F0Og464MF@Q6lcyQ@U6/PZijLcj12tgH@qskEISJn11gHQeMKxgE5ywxg/kB6MPWeMFvBbknm5e4Zhw9/BrC35N/uDvClh8yIlNnNi0xKbiQT9wVsTNi/MZ9kB3sXBxfz7FIKjBXQzFN6ABD3SHyhyMUJuw3hGAZAISYVDU@HxzegKjc9K@8PwSRm@7vWNJ3Q5JJtI6JAJq2x8eja@h2H5BCXuE8YTCmfMY@4PFhTaUouhxrQTFX98UQSyPXYECFoeMUEKLjSJJ31Qmc/8suqNHGuDYjMJMJK1/vqE5j2@gL3oGcV05iO6FAaNUvAjv8W9cZ@Ddwlt/MLtBwjQgQqrkzkKG0luJPGsAyMog15SNwXFeOr9k8zHvg4LZ4YVg@b/U2hMQJ@e6IR7NqZ3dI5JH5n@iYF/vKI1leCyFG3PJzOGVmV0M5wNJkN55kUkwpHzW7vnmYQjSoAYDkdQF5ZnGBkKMPPBnUNhyPqwcOjxQnRd7DrPBJlyFaeDmeGTI40I2R9SMLd/jcxtMztATBQ7MA8QUr4rX88eDD0k@Uzlbu3b0yvMtUB5msVgxudmZM/DvDoRjN2ej3SGIJPLeTCfoSsbk6ndH9mW2Dhzm1N7UYVtCySfWSdjQg/HyRkhgZNPNh3XPYUw90gOCVHE7wp5DmH09nAhg815bHE0aDBoSNVUkAkacBKE2Iko6fwaGqsIHQOu/oxB0FFeWrz900i5xNLKi55GElLQBfiHptnS1DFUC/rc8SdOwmBU/ZmpeEFWusGNdkQHv7CSY2Jv1TbVdOT5oIDlEtvH3anvjO3Q5jQZGgYnJnmW3Re8L@J8psQe7I0k7/jJv8wH@QMQK5AjfwgluJGZLtwey2zGk1TqyYUng@M39H0EheeM74uftZFV5Vk5hYOPKCnf@XjAi2Vkhxow7YEJM6JKnv8AoTe0@4Df4s5eICtebKS@e5o1Wz9cjC83UxfjXy9@MQkTuSSrXTYtNuRhtlqx5FyBnTFrhX4qrzRP8P304mIcLnAxJrcuPr2XJABEsqnWD9nLX7OA0MWGaW5mLzaYIKEhQ0yyD7eXRfDZJTQ3wlhkN4wn5qapBj/1Xd4UsLfSXxxDfmHyX8BCKZVkpgc9Z9oDUBQDRDcRoGKXfbWd29nO74Am1Hfm6alzg/tt2ru5cuYgSniozsLWc/FLiBtChLife/Y@vJxDPwf9MaaDphH1ZEILuYTKaU7tGD5bQZ0M8wSUByqnkAQY4mL6ZWw8fESF3xLAcqosZbRg10GN@1K4f3ruCNuxPVzXotEhzJHoZcA@ImRCTSNkyXgrOdRU0yVJwWYZUbp2YJARCAxvdkPbLcbuOC2FNTOT3EchGqNmhpjbNzpHl6ZoaIY@k8JU8qnIH3338r//d@3njdnG0Xb2wxT@zjZ@3th7tcGP8AC/XqhftxtHGwdYbO9@Y5EFHRgeX/73/4H6R38HOPhlcQD/HO0qWHuLjaP0IVX5deNoDx7y29vQ7v/9r/@CPjxjjQ0z2zxrW4IQ21cUKdlj4l34LqrYS1ZLk8GykseFBWGwhyHo5vADHaPm269yZKbbkF4Vt@j@M@jNfH8UucWTY9aMXIXYkqH8KUAy4gqH2ECaQSoXip7QfDeU2wYyb4Cm@OfzzJ4HGsA/pTuH36TvuvHcQ5ehZ6wWwQCmuEXQ5/nhKPddwnfvKCSUT8m@EiFRtZNr7asX@8AO71xnNuiEvSTUdB117DvnKoN8mHG6N6BTjb2h@@M0ewssOcpvv8r20LifJT/u7IQgpSeLzC8gCMpsJKAYktOpJaYwAu4I/sIz5igBgf7EP5NS2TlAyp44HbZhhTM8QZFGs1yp1y0@HsbuZAJROkX/ggCPeUhkWg0t8vxiDDVr9YJIbPkFuRzpvCZi846cY2XSkTR7w1IGWxBgqA9oHVT9yRSnfQpColpTgMBFMna327blt5TxJKECzy3jybUznBwmyDcMeoN3kYGELunPYuZKKOkBWhDSaVroENbImdmgoh8m6A3q40ELM7ylgM9aSTem1cUna0@WlVp99/AEz7QeaPqOm76DEUUpIWjH55kgF85Y6MV4bTlEU@XUaeORWmzD0JqnUmBNM/QHMfB4WKo9DEuQ3aEISKBa0B3pVaYPm0W6MPDIncMxe2xa5DxgxkYQ/GipEsBZ1bMMyk7YboYbgwXizB07BfRQ5jvjMALiUCVtGYxJAFr6rGKHJRjqQ23iMJqKUNgRS25LY9gPSeDAWEoBJBg4Hm9qgQ@2wbuHD1rC0RL6JNDwkjCRpXoFUraooBqOAiXV4sZRM2M7Vasj/GQ9PZkLCJdHepHI5bdf7OzuvXz1LcaMP5G9jQeDlTKoBUyubYBBEnUKlGx8f3iYSCb4FSb0Wm4SoceBxQM4dOu6Mwkrfnx6mM9JYLkEwbqjxFRcXZorCWQAcepkcEcAHSU1TaRS3xVa2LHLi675K/yXsFRtZjg0NdvDwS82k14bh3ccEEFpjkbOyJ3i8TguzDZldsG8@rCF8Be9rOP26g7eUIW@rsz20NCp62JQwtS96V/r3JFha79owoQBgs@miwJpUK8djhQlnVrDCmVRaXCoatEXhwpea7kH6JSLWwLKfAwcphlMBvTyt6WnKc6OJGxCmOcBI1bxCFFzHdXZmbhz7IrKWTmKmMyENvB8uBndsxWEO9gPAXyldoKZj7TuNoG6MCX6stdqTbLYoE@6r1zgclgOuAKZHmOlO5jWS6OKWqtJbpilHiJLnnhx4Ce0C6rCOCJeMTDzucdJqeJaVS@QIGohlNYkfxGz/PMcnWQBTvog4zxFXk4UNB/RtwPPo3zesrGEKT1KqRAMpMenEnEA0W6TS3BHcgUcUXqsUBorHm2@IZVcJvFWUR5gX1N1YksOetJUQFHjnFnEpwX2v3pWskS5Av@cfChbKCgfF/@B/fYTZq3GNy/xzRdE9UQNARFUmuHI5xZ9pn7GECVglpzF6UsCBHHxJcMG1iPJGylYqZ5I2vOkboXm9mXAFciuthTClXVUThLMmkI2kCdSeSfTmcy1KBX6AhuvlleaLVlYTQs2cT08sTWaPAla9SExKdcAsR0FkVYgAm5/EjA8e6CT5G1L3UUxdvUknqdDLMsKFYjtJ1kge5hnV1LmIbbYlmyxXcBxfIgviG8f5A2@vyzMHI/wxtMv4430@syR/rdgjsqfwx0vJHe8KODaw9wx7kwdWpEoopOS2rkxHHO1oD243R30B2gf6mk/sRM5SwNACx5dS2ZTPEg@h31bsZyIVPyHreh@hE5C27t7xhd2fkd2fqeAay49lp3/qZ1P/8ad35Wd3y3gXhMz8lK0k@Gvv12PA5EwFX4RO7wo7nIx80t7uid7ulfA3TRmmP/wnqZ/p56@lD19WcCMCXzgwClcH@ZmlkSKjVK1GrhbZFQG4hRmBYznShN1L7xR2hK94Y13fYjSuvhi/F9J/F/hakRPdSSrrcUo@7o8q6ccLM@SJV@eh0FW3BPurwz10vsrN6xAH5EbFC/SZNiaSkUFBHKLPwanTZlAfgxWX3/zWRdnXtsptxJnhtUUaNYI82YwxVnypcIqAesTZuQZWtJKzfrp1v9iMozsn2QUGiCPQ3uH9wzJnURXwXCs@LXsjNYdhN2QOkeIVSQ5CdmZjPb22eXJ6lWNEltE9sV4JYGP2jhdMmagcjQPIDIZAW0ysr7SqtA1V6kX/Ab6zoXiuyx7/EVc@q3k0m8Loi4Vg1WksqXBT/JioKdt7@4@tAdwrQz@wQmYs6D8A7Pq/wWHC8vuH8UeUqf91vG8DS1ZlKHn6eYyAsuIcJniDZSZFvDKmPEV@h@895NPbRtatmVQVjzDKL0tN9B2YV91uk6vfz348afR2J38PPVmN7d388Uv@YRhqOT8KZOzFirvG2mmWM7XnJgmIkmb01rW5gAEGuaTbDUJG0KS@XzSbBUK25emwPk54nxMfD4QACARdewN8Z4kcrPws4fTULIHQzS216Ojf2@GMedAstTQHl11bTEvCPS/Tuctgd5g8m0HCAkkIjtMqgOr58Q0TboXRl45kdQhF5KW/lPv6rQ/qrJ9TiQSEiX4WaUDATS2@EV9C02LTC6XYhOYj78MumFLCdtk/JoytR6qBZJPt3cuzQKQ6QN9QYa/toczPhFM/WL6njDOzI8kwK2zxIsc7iI5MxS4oCF9QBug3zFTMkdwysX91dbV0HetHR9GKwB/GSocopX2Ywumvh@6A8BgKrjHrjs8xfFVLViSGpZ4FXQmyISIYc1v7GHPHwWVrXjATpUh3gn3kXLIIrVDAxMhhCRGz1/pgmDqa2zWlZZivz4eNgDGV@SusARKxxcrLRVY4hJaQ0M5fWjTiNbj4fVmnE48phMBc7Z8JChHdMBv2vsN8X2tDqN/a08HaNhia1se2sg4GZiffXL4n8nJFJuoSE6u7V2YVz5kmmHmEnLxfVqFcmr5Jei98iU2QOsOdgAv0FVdwN2sT9kNH0d6DZQfmM4hDmWwyN4nsB357K2YOr8nhbpkEpGW8mPctAtzN7L2FH2MU68ig63ogNNrD8mlXlyyvBJ8foXjjDnHYA@Y2uxOtiHOZwNYxBeBTzMJN@QwpktZlISIgXFu/ugE7lxb4kr@kPl1JKba4oG0oTz912aQaHxF5xSwFrtjbImXeOZODOFDBAEOZ0DejFsRsTH/Z1Zsm6u7C6Wwn96yYBnpcmhQ47vr3ugI5B7tZ1BePcEeoq/jS4QYXIZZYBmCWmql6zDuDfLTMmfjkVS7jbl/2m1KtdJuo/zQbie5FRYmNCFIu/eieNW9maan9vXItsd/z3Y8L42Xb09mhtEBsh4ciGTlrJzEUCv/U2aygHFIb6aFzNMvSOTAN0YiEY4yLTUaolGqV981BX0zaEw67nDoSPFAyki1aRfvCC0POjMlNrGUp36NbEwrZNCllKLkeQ3ChXuIg9tuo/t/u53ynGFPG52N4An@e9N8eyqalHCwWWlQPsRGTFGEkcEASFJPEfGDp@VaqfnxXQWoOBoeGQfqDxQ6onoHs8Fs6BwdZPkvv/NmCxQFFhMHtED5LksvoW6WKx9cud0F/OkObgV9Okyoo//C1AFxa3Dr7ENlnbaEYM91ZwGCWaiPQCW0LCOoKuiVQZCrlWuiIOwuHtmAIKiUB5xUHgaGDHoLkXyRzAw80utTZrhlefOJlEaT/DODLSYtkbzbSsZs/eGBaLwpAi1fn9aOi6eY8etdpY5pLFeNxVW/DUyDEixdy5AMf@XwNHccEiroy0xKrNGP4VLfk2gcfvcx/G5FN@qV11XM57gacybpofiUK@Tvw59u0acq9gtdQkHf7pcxWIHKyWnx9YNYoFK3tO/RV7Qwx35d0VTt7HUNU1Bi6sxVLbrjPmga/Ta2HENe9RmbbuNFHd5a9FYtH9fKD9C8P@TORBvFxnB6rNVUqXZ@tnpxkC7C@TCUDcNH9Lz57rxphGv6ixVMGFqnLDHXliptakmflLm5Cv5xsVERlVPKeKp9Il@XoTNS0C2xsHhRARWU1k7HA9HFUokKUYwpROOa6WrV2OXIvgL9@Wbm7GMcaOHT/WS@P3Mn8gGnGub4LXCsa@rTfdfpm/sXxqf7BLd9mACGThx9uufF6mKc5KtoZimJqD6Zl/D2kTaNCDHKlXr1faWs6NHQPodKAtGqJfXVp1dnMO1g3JxGMco/Y8nsMzEjlFrahOkLUZ4hJAkEU4bB8DP6XfWn6FWbpkkOb/evXNz8YBfuDm68wm7u@b5PF4nIUnMM0tIXx0jS9Rg5QXUYvcv@xO7@Zp2jviDs@oMdArEWtNKrISaugP@Gv3sHLww5olfubOaO0pTWWg0v1wp9x8kU@uwDgMm1ujZ@jKka7cmXkHuJZGvxlppmlNr5pFriTb4BUn@xXq99aERWwyW@tKdT9@588vuwpsipcYMnSUFaxQTSTcC6NuiKC4NWMbrAbubPS66lFYspxEMpS10YXE5ndtQlCBMzu00XEQa/vmoyE9HK7t34X5JsuHv8rjQL06mOlf44QgW9e4BOIc5ZSSiN5n84d51C2/@SRNNZ8Hei2uo1j1K2P7jmBQJMs/J9Myq0IPnpXmqd8vjiywi@vP3qXQsEQmphBXtIfH2049W3B1b43mA4XCX4@irefFlelhLlipqa@jdfJS/XK43a6fuKKFdfV5viffH0vBIRm6d4NnTr8EG2bGrq9PFCCKAfnVBpDSc1BaKDoRUUB8fnWBTshqfhaDPq@QZNS/QcDgcZzJIelzV0i6qf72fsjp3YllQTgV5eiEvxFAUN1ZK/JtF6RV/Cde7wdtBDCVceCP2aNKOmdygm3XqSaJjhYAnytsXrVvEey2WD8FDa0HiUQvQNKIuA85fm8iJ0vW7t7bjakhSRo0KQaK7NiHk@3DkPFLvlzm0vdw4I9lXdkwiiXSsDjaYA3sOYdVzvD0cM2nwcMdAK/2iqYVRLiHJmRJdfPqEgF4RVXCIbbtEsCJ@GyaC3fzgLiqRaCeNMTdqlFQWWtUfXk3WmqH6OGhykzp@iEm8tTWDzsSlccofLQ5Zf2b/ktH8FOr1F/2/6u0jsWbz10CUX8cf31opT/YcAmQ8Md@xSGNkUqmflyrvKGV5JI/5R@fihVi@jSbgR3Rrkxe@RIfQ9scmE6uk2Z93AqipwMcpGMXPVPVEgx1yLoduBWYEjQcYy2onnwVEjg@fgF3iQNy@HTorVQTwtE2TOSIapsQSD2UQsr/N0zMwdQnA7y/xAmTQfmrxcHa@nWKq7WLNuPqYu5qdft@3tFfXXbf9FXH2yzLKxSNqrECP@s1ghRPvrpT5EaIBZNUAPT/Kl4TN/3wEU/34jSNavrxw/ZXT6owbx1V@D6P/f1XTNyjtxlYdrVt6NqTxbt@W9uMrrtvxyJeP6ps5l7rVE1GL3Gews7W5/rUh/0oqk7J4PLUrxg4Z2v7@G7c8cNrK8fv7AkSHyr5H7M0eObcGfP3RoDf1r5P7MkSN79NdJcGiIjAwiGUij@KHqHsUu3A67V6BdkwCEPz4kQqJFM4JCYM10UmuQyVy3MVQnv0wh/FJd70sZjZ120OotzdZCeaxLxipcrup12HvjffFUvK2VqydxHhxLBPKcP2xKb5Oi75MtsOTiR/K@iTOaTdtsWl6bqiIWCDoJ@mOO4f2xkwz9klqq@CXZhmX7Ma7W7C/r1zPX8H2Wnrt3Uxfjzz28YUmFeI/smcaBvh2lWMZLlU9r53UY2HrjMyZ61/19BtadrKQjmzi/hPtv2UFfrYFRTvIXV57U0Z7JUogZfN5Kxjtoa6ZOiqXpDV07QI3eYpJ7fr1k@g23kf6aNtLrtbH5NW1srtdG9mvayGbjGlmxLJUrx@evRVY03tQ@xJehL941XhCFtzt1po4zXrWEhdcwqPP78Hqs5fxPswJGdgh/NPzZEan0qP1eLkc/gXTi32OhL0La4PDw8egMxiqF8lrDQxeg/YHj8zn7RdwYMVX4mOI3pecKW/xZ7SxNBviQIZ7vsPc9W3WTvOdhkkBplffcm2lHP0@h1LQ4RvwlyEybWoqcenAHw9uUwg60HOKDcV4q3wOFvgqVSZTvBonnW3ZM3YIBj20k8MP9mkZ8L9eldkILkxJPiDsvxvGbSXzfYxfLwNu5teQAfNlKIkbJS8WQRIhYMBs6oHQ6jVU@JZlRk4VP9yATEih4vF@NR4wHcCyusV7PSyVX@zIv833QvLmSoEvjHAsvEnLiA192nTZXxI/5E0HmaA6xhzxHossj9IskCg8euc1DqZzDtUXS0iN5VpKTj9MCWdMSc1iC8N@4BX9tl/HYibDeAMc7hmvXlNFlwsbKeUTL/VAdrm7EzKVYGOFqcRIbnvwCweOpvWJz1Ph6KRiROEJqAXzGvnSc@BDnU9U4tn7k1D@yPvSUYhFMbDw996d2Mnm/Ym3gOUb1/csTkCoWEN2Mi1PUcTtahRohQdqOJ@kCeubqklhIi1dKmSun74SyzgXQV88tuRNPkCpn7tj5AhLy30eJGMOB4Qns@5vYSzYSTSnjo20SK9IkVlAAkX/GTdkJCdWv5ekwu65Ch3XEoqhXimXRaNbFyflZSVTPGk18UTuhD6fVs0rMqc4iflj07U8RvKWofRmkflx75Q0D4g3xX2kVJm1eEVyOvfR0I2b3x/4RLn9kjhHtQ9FacZRF8TKesGqECo/TIL5iC2BfBor44PJBQAPOifFvwAXx1HiYLx7VBjSNYOwK7waTeuFm4sxBB/GS5rprVKuww8sS7tW/0U6pCQixO@VqsSNmMYqTllfY89SVGJ8xcExCug8@RraQaqa6JcNYOe@oQH6F3S9wc5ILQtTDKTQ8Ef2teAyrbrHUrJTF20rzTa3c8D9FnHkxTjcapbsc@qaF4JqR4PzkldO/GUdjTCn0bdxdEzLHzsaGtWYoV1N8yGumM3SBRksY0e3vyZXReqXi6Wnx@LQiSRMN2Js7HanHYs7f9sSeXUd7wGqsirj1i8FuP01Gsr@8SkbR0yFEukWDEXkX0q1lvUgRJLRpPBZ5zvHigLQfry2bChLjaOUyTIcgtY1pYGZRw0AuEOmOSOf1gPSnWtQxXacj06bzawvTI42dO5pqtp@U1vifEMi9ZnhlTkZX5uKCK3MUW8lO/RQSvR/EWCaOdnK7Mh78sbhwJrFMdRQO8hcTd7joD114hgegeLbr3GbHN8OhgVt@d9DrhQdBfz76ZhtvxHQ6164AbP4/)

Code:

```
g[>++psg--.--._+._q]
```

Make current cell nonzero with `g`, then set current cell to `54` with `>++sg` (get third char of the file, which is `6`).

Answer (score 0):

## 426. Python 3.2.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 427. Python 3.3.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 428. Python 3.4.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 429. Python 3.5.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 431. Python 3.7.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 432. Python 3.8.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 433. Python 3.9.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 434. Python 3.11.0, 18615 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 3.1.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265293).

Answer (score 0):

## 436. Python 2.4.0, 18712 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 2.3.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265432).

Answer (score 0):

## 437. Python 2.5.0, 18712 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 2.3.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265432).

Answer (score 0):

## 438. Python 2.6.0, 18712 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 2.3.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265432).

Answer (score 0):

## 440. Python 2.1.0, 19055 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPZdSD4saPT8yMuE6wCQCDfeIMAyWKxutiql0hWd7sBFCqRSADZTGSiMhMkUCQrujUOrWTJHluWbFmW3bK8npVXnhjvxMy6HSPvRNgTsV8mHPPJP4CyHbthO6R/oD3n3swEQAKsanm969jYBDLzPs4993XuuefcV3Z0f/CznyXwIk9ce9q33YAEph@QrmedmJ5I7kzJtm75eVXjOITa8frjoekEfoVLEIUQW3f6Y71vkp5lB6aXJb5pko5pu6fgrxKyOXbGvtmtg00jxDFPyb5jWF3AQAL32HSsl6YHfjlC7pr2@fA8IIY7HOpO1ycjz3IC6psn5IkOlt7YOCZ6xw883Qgs1wGvwkIUxQVbiZCHruebgMk1TN93EVd5AUSRyTs6xDeyzckVzIpC3rdMr0toKkaeydKiqOS9o3v3rrpq5AuC65B7mMIrXjmyMw7c/eAq/jzZ6ZuOTlSxLKpXPQtQToFpl@SSfNWrCFVlBpZxNZ4S2en1LMckDyGvVz3LxPB9wTc8axRwUJXknuVBNethdRJDd6DasFI3iDkcBVMiMELQbTuuZJ/oPhn7Y92mcM542DG9CNAPdC@wnD45tYIBCQaWH4ej0P5IN0yha9rW0ArMLrEtCOT2QiyA2umSY3N66npQ9yFO17GnENA0rJ6FQaJ0AEK8UsHAZHiG@hQIxwmASohOfEiGbUbY0lwC4O@anXGfuONgNA4IpK1r@XrHBqSdKemaPX1sB1nSAT@oEup@OjCdkKoBnQgojlyWqo/GNGnmjPj1bpfIQNCQjmOTWFBqNFkVomngTlwPSg2gohSFyCiBszyaE6hhqLOeWyF5WQb/vdgFU6vbvhsmZjFp6OlAo6V1hnifeG7f04dQGl2Tlul7@0@Ib7ge2OBGWNawbkJj6AHZ3CTJvUd3k6QeV4vodbi4imrkDKogEXmSE90eA4XM14QL9ePFoTmssuRaskKSUCyqTHI5koP2WyJqHgpJkctgAEagagrcBaKWSE6B9pYnGgBrKjTuAvhAgyA5GRzLySzG3/P0vmWbDHsfsRex@UAwFZ5yjmjQMrSCxqD7rt1joAZNSJFoJVIokmKeFOFZJmUVUoLR5qDR5OEuwA0Yy5BMQKRqkGhZZchm7QLoGGlxl/T0oWVPwxhoFAbJK6QIWCE/CmBXS4AF3pqGtwZ3CbEtXvO4gwHUxkA/AfSCbR0jOzNjjoZVLMFL2tiQKOtE3syi9wcYPRQtFGq@RIoQfQFKJAdJgJJXSxA9eGp5SAJAaPkCZEyDu8Ay5w9M2w5RDXxERXNQlOGG3BShfEpQY1ATqowFXYQb7MBRVWCdKvBJFVifCuxKVcGsYbQAh1VYgOov5Fg0A90/hohYPGqXVgp0B4BGwVpANqlgwQEGqEkCxa9hQklOQ@KBxEOeIC3FAgHCKCmklCOlIoEyLssE6kyBdCFlKcChFUiPgsiANhQgDgXSpEANKIBU0fKEm6sARUN/CKtBWCguJQdhcmCGylQKeEM4oBgFolQgTlUtzwgX0qbmIb95jVK0WoAaL4IflJsKaVWBzJCM1RL4Y9gSlGEJCb6YzLKC0LEcoKawiQB9QmFA9SgUL8CCWS2GBK3bo4Hewf6Ahez0MGgBm04BixGCypg9eOewNCEpUMsqthBIvgpUodEWBu9cHL2tAJIGoje7FmXqNnYsSlxCxSwl0o/0UTArNqVAUzSaBoPYTWVuLjBbCxim2deNaewJLTMbe85cCxq6qpQ/zxDJOXT1gRu7Y9@eIYkNOZVGZZ5Y9sytRN26pt7tWf7g1SytORpJx9QDxzqexZLPZ@cKVZ/zKKDHglNRm4cNLAG6uP4ATbO8qEWEGblxBS0kWVFo8jpmb@z0TaFcmksf9QnGXgCd0SzOMnP2rH4fOvYZHiVLs0k715lznqbQ1jTo8yNHLF2M07Ogy79NjAGILLFnmeEvl2c4NBVxTPUOSgICiHDQc5Sxr@tZE9K5bdCeZpZAjZaTMbBGEXBlJfBc5dJIJqXCHG3QkntZkmOWjVdL/Mi1nFSSJNPcBQf9ExNL53t36ATfx54N@2okXeiLXSppzFhqyol60zQU2qJgAD21jQJUxzR07LWxDzNpHxzhsQKRQCQgW5ruCcq8tCNdiMannW3HQxEXJKOu6XkEYUEu9rO0W/bHHd98MUbZa5auHvTzJogDPd2y4wTQvkUPqNAA76QP8U0Xk93z3CHtgIbY7dquO1oh4kAnf4qI7run5izpMxlAH41skLTA3WSCHiTmVKfCOpXs52NlCYJAGA4qHBDSqEBCsTzToGUfZh1CayDLLCaxQtT6bQ2x3JkTwTRoLCCe@BjGGdt2BWQj0yBaXeqaJxK6MDFtUTzDNESCG4hfIYqODtI4ppymIsZ0WxWpSHgU1azvDhezxvrc/TjrAwuFKftUn0Lt9aC7NSf6EHQGgoI5tFwyBIphNYg1AcoFZmufdF0nGcRYTj0QfCHTcU6ocI1lElhDE1QnF4JgjedoorHHpynrTIGUaWnlRKorsZRcKSiRu1pQzCE358AaC4iI3bGBpYZxWw6lIBChfNQLPGCVzI0LPNJs6nB7IAOOQvVQRAMCHmLS5rQMn7X2UFo3KEaUa03HB8XFF4mFyhtQft/tAbGdWpB3YFgQdIbboIWARRA7TURD5GiRIwENj21iEWM0IuAOnRKQ5z25BGKr@5FFXoKnPQC1wxh73pRMRlAT1hCgAsPt9YB6X5qjAaAgwy4xpgY0T6hkSj3@wNFHXNelbMYYLWZ2Zls3AcZBdWb3yS@SvgmFD6JuD5VJJPxZNkYjmhFaILrDxGBHh/LCjBijKS0cLjEL0XNdEd27rulTknG945gBYGS@2acNBFpbb8aShijWA606VB3pAv8JGxnixwi5pZnBqEJaeMd0oAEZQJvQ9KESsWZ3SA/09DnhFjUU3TDMURBSi0uZmuXMaQqP76GmQF2FEJnoD7j1bbJ5hXYANKafOSkXNSdM@ihUYHTkuOFggEDFj1hZZfzFnl6LHiBOrsTOP0eYhRQ851ekYUQbBqpNlFWMA2QoyCMtY4AcMUCeQyVxaHPe@Hr2wW0@em9IhF4cN6ZGAebDiVLshOlYjUOA276OSBzZiKu@4ICgCw6vQa37wyWY3TiRdnfeVZR0EVjj65AOXcddghUKM8aLIIs@tC4oMR4i79DtmBhpc/EX6gjZ9mx8Crsz6ElHI9eDlsFYz5SOQdAqm6OuUHVPxT1GWiR3FjtY6DiS2O0H2BdCgJGtAy1gE8OWCjqXDvwCWBlTrYHzuSzGuQTTVk9xhek7pR0AIyboUR3HRLVN96YMCWQPOmmIaEoszwNmeIJdBeuJoi5FpHQKPYPe7SJ/xeKg7f5q5CJS9O64Y02u6u8GOoof@dyJ7pEequ4eiB7QiFLJnp9MV6k7DTnnxUvuKJBoUPbkAZACiVDlqZ4vYldxDxjN4dQxUvxCE@OzhB8HvRKfBgMGZJIaeRcUhqupQyUCiWZ4DO2a2qqkD524IMBTQDeaEvSQRPTQPZA2oBGCrlkudzs6OQfu4RFhsssUkkgxUcRcHJfpdOO4woLAtMznV2RR@J5BDcJc34Y5QHCac9pJLBTgG5YEDciDgySFPSw6UJmP@VHphjmOHTreR1JMIEmTs1gEhg4gRRNjgQhiGVbQDoWW27cj8WWtVgNiA5kK2GY3Pa/XRmOhInBqABapTBJGIgbuYYBtI5WG/CLwBUsNCE9AqbU6OQsGHrQ4ar/gAAiKlXOQkqOCDev5kXU87l6taAcdEYjHVgeik2UEfJUDEYC1htpNpZpcKFXQfZNYqki8GJ6ivka81BUrlA/BPNNHIbgWJmWuhlOYgpBWlxYRCxq6zQh6d2rYoUjATNDYGTfqQPKPwyGwmBFlQ5kgarTXWipDgs2B4SFPdo7u18K2yDyljuVUFhxs19Bt6ryO4HwU9sH@nYOdg19sL8FhW53KVQfJypUK2NWOJ0LfGUs5Ua2sz@OYIb7bvhk3BlyE4bnQmwjuZE5UmhrQuUyi4nx88IWrRQKSEBYHjQHMeF8RaRgMCF1cR/cHVzph0s9kIMo4SARLhH0S4YwNmHT016P0PBm/fImVdzVRo9AdU2aPdYYgcpT2nSiciJ5XBLDIq9NjPSINC7Ko5eD8xsw0Dxml5x2Una8mhgrUcyTzzuN7ewc1ijYcXRMoiOQHIEvpXlcEmrfHoIgvgwH2ByaDZMRZwlGqpmldWsCGsVDAs7olK/ADAtR4RJcI9jDKmj@AtO9ezRt1FYyYAqidYrgqV87LQ8bnTehcOrCLM1DxXdaLUo9ZZxU7Le2xYt/FbsvI581irjzfbRmzOLvzSOl0AvQDkdzogdexL6CLOJMiQ7E6TP7hg2sJ96kQCaqAEKXMt4lI4/JtDrUXwSJJX9oFPc21TfF9yvF4wqclKRnNKIiGT1XQOfi9iRWk5DR7K2mAhdh3dvbVuxFwOJhNxzOo0oAaOfZMXg@nCA0faMRxbbfvkg0Iw6TDKEIQm1Zmc6fvOtdqSEdHzGoCZxmB/@LwjT6CvsZ6SdVHGmpeaWXzlbrjnwKXVgoaFhItIYpKovDiR/qJDsU1y/fh/od70IkoeVmOzTK9oAjmwtDiQpMx50odiAARiWF6lmYwnpa81tojD2FuXhAzHTK6OODOzHupI@WYorQUfmmS3nWvlfhH7vQKaYELIy0wzBXZ/qMnD/Yf7T3c@aAZqPn8gj0nlwtQcBBfB2QhccDKDVvrBmuamC1El4C24WHzAi4wBgUlmmca@x4wbhFBRJaAFVTDJnRT77oDJ@mnr2bmFH2FjxyDkdBDbHwMNAwIinbXRmXEYxPe2J8j/QyCYORXJAla@WDcEUFplT4yXFvvSzQcdAy2LSmouuw/xtENf1kISIw/NVkINsQFosOUjiPq9tAF5YVOmyNrICmGno5d2VZ/ALowzq2bXlqMKZjmRuqChgC6shTnjTJgaoOyDd9RPfGMtN9W1BKja0VWcxIfgS00f4Bd65mgOqWgt4KiSF@xkubt5m0yBS6NmK4iSRBxgw5y@AT7ApuAIEnHTlHPjwqHcgscNUVeQcvoxRjHdIFLSXk5V1QKeQnUMlDTQGYVcORNGOqBMRACVwB8gtuj4wZzVNjzDd3piRuhIUosyH23IKta41mz6bRAQG/epmnDGevGtNVQWukquR5kI4RPV4F6F7KHtBs5AO1SI5AmfZMV/KyrX2dnXZ22ri6RguEo7HOEEXm4A4LUSxf4ddecb3sYQJr3lDYWYCUEfiUtGRCyMSiHDywpCRoU9LRAehKmSwChF8VDoBzgW3MByGw0IxaYpsEA@IdGUrvUlL4u4aKzFnKNxaTg0LA4mgLLo0DItAUNExR50AhHDAMmJQkqEEo86J9kSaADCUcesPQRVBMb0NqFjgDUOR@HIgPsgnHOZszGhrFJhlYc8NwRPiS68PIm4SKCBsSXP/ysF@KJxTaR3NGR4qAUrkh2YUCRPEUWAH35lAR0pKFrohqPyyaeOhYqIiJHfQXoupLrbTHw1ggPcV3@8E8vP/nu5dc/ufzkW5ef/Prlp398@em/WxNeoY5Z38w0m4KYbbQIn7yW@Ft76q2dO7fulGgKQZ6ExP8fv/Trf/cbv7KY9iXx/vjjr/3441/@21/55G8@@/jHH3/pJz/6@k9@9JWf/OirbxSv87//qmv810/cMMpTHBqZjzCMD6IbDKAXvQ9SW2Pj1ukZWVtbg@Bra1tQE2tbWyRDtuApwHMN@s0t8M3Cc4s0wHeNtMhFiwMN1idLRvtEOn4umroxaAO3NMyUlhahyzs7n5yTwaAxEaGdH/PGBt@6oLNLtC/AGReW6F2stEO6cgbT/i5038w2S/yqqBtSsyE3W82zVLObSTcvpKzSAi27beHDT6nphiKKArghb0lJ4lnpQorTNqGQACQaA2@WMjphxxbyoC7NCP6eNYGeCFglENL8mDxlLXRyB4dWPzRHg6k3DxCPV4F8imPPs/UhuIwG@d88f3nJws@LQgs6ciQxMjgQC3HYCyWN0ZTxRY6ltCktLE@KeqwToTd0A116TwR1Q5zraJJrSUkQoA@hPgwTzfZDyzdAtdAd0x3782N0S4cOMXZwPRqMgX3vDqwRZxoDFyh9G3CSeJYECxknfAQ2bRQF6xoi3NiskWXgFAP0xnTpjgWVT1svHcVQaNQnum1147HsfGH0Qoxjq9IwRMaIrL7jeqYABQEhOLpOiS6D4@rRbO4@HSm6xitDX9oFIN@1zCBL7tmuTkvUdYAW5qgR50Jm4UGfhSAHZpezHSL0QLQQWQ14Zlfa4OjcpusNgF1CbnDKRo3raBh6SK4/6orBBIJyKeyg5j2ZNgRC2inpqqpaMPK9SuSHtACFPYCqQS3OAZUw8hIU8EyHVbvHhlEinfbR47t7bKyBdk7YHeG4U3vodscgh4V6xoHp9LNkD6jIctwhsFInCv/y2D5w3YBpxWBZNZLBlExrOLZ1OkZydRjjxnCG23FtOnRyU9AZ/NjzdVtngzaR7857D0E2fnp0WBMrc0CSfjK8MW4ct1seLSvP/fmZOjpLGU2n@Iww@fU8j91ctNASmUvoUUKPIS6lBFkx1KKpNXYMAc8U@QJhV6obMZxC4ZiMNIvoTFGp@0nQ6y04a9T5WEBeYs@cc9SZLa9cUIe8zgwoz4BwreUCzDyiAoWJl1yuhCtSOLacA4h15lGiHjpdgCng0P2Cb5n6zlZgovQTcrB4wn5g2tEE3IE5dHGSCXpJG2czQLRHQZatkTShrxjhXAJl0zhDBV2CDgGvClrQxEYCg@YSa7TZdCxHwokibl0i4QhxlTYc0LrZzJ7PWKgLmjEdfNissxlh1Dw8pvRIbOx6vQ0oNuvVaMHaKjCMKZmMwShWmjYIQbNJJ8GvZTVe0uDTIWmOBqlyvgRC90SVheakuNc6T0o@LYYe4ZvNyS1Z/QBkElyNuH5b6ptVuh5oRXlVI58kZdhhX85RKDa8awyAu5DMZLEooX7GTs@1uwKbSwJaI0wLwQoKJ/TjVZLhYljT8qIFknSFKguKXHVubeU1vFeqtH4dYG41ZowIxQdyfpw9OSeN4yw5Ef2RbQUgIqE8MQhXFTlX123S@Szd8/Spz4XrQWpk5@Cd9xpyi2HghjrOD5VYLU6i5b@gtXnuGBdsgwlXtQRWQHt9OmtvYX5ByIEAdCoBkg84WARVEkcU5ohKPub5LC89E/S5lEnFpekwS8z0hdiz9SAwHUZzbJJudXGz2ZQwmhqNfiscmq8Qmc5fWD1IJfhBEqvk8Oju3sGBiAJdKrmH8xwVaI4gOoIwsirTUUnOZ75CbnWT5BaGSaNyy0FTA3W9HYYHoq4C0Y9NnM1BttM3vRQ4pnGKwgBnOitEAzJpLCwgXJtkBLSMYmQpULa3GLLK0vQ/dY4d9zSu8QpQfIaWJBR36nYFpcy0OHasF6IP3QsVNAEk1Kegl6itpygnW1fS4eKzIU6wglBNBUTIQaNBQGfi1wGYJ61Wlc2UAyz4gRuWLs/TqqCrxGtKVPU1cAZBhmIIg9dekWcNWSi3MuvLUNGFWOECb5b/ObyIYRG1by6Ndj1F2/u1hszSwGbMGPd@6tPlj4vbHCpknRl4NjJLwaPFRZTp0LVIi2uKFlcsQSNDVkIHLDAjEUtIhMvvQ5ql/pTzg9aLwahDKk3O4kJXscjJ@TktQ7KuElqGYFIIq4yLSCsGxvTAhdw8CJfez8sEtLWGyy2wzTY5vhJr86Isyjw6MTldOrkijAon1DfSzJkwaDnHLp0OiU1tWVTyKADGoYfH9vWQuFKTPhZA6WTqDFZd4sOEt2GnRx9LAOisQDjfTB3oeHMo@oLMqEsH9EWHnpfEvLjGYiHacA0n7WLBTIQXr4EUyiUK3Ot0rFWgUAi4eCp6LwED7oSErIo5UZll8eoyHLJQvuGi0vD93z7uQjlfr4UB9AQ4ABcb2tA3Y40IvZWVEgZFC30sr0A2Tjy2LZ0WADW9DqWhe5Al3Y4Ny1HTuWhBgP59iCPrYc0CDeIDJMobyImlnE2MRe/lkSybW3KAJxqrYK8sS2JR0VkQ0Ne6tBCYlGOZNBDlTawSzAmbiZjTl5FPvT5R0dohQomW1ftgHIzZE4Ta11aiNcL7pjYYQsp5vaOYElvGfUOVe/rxuOsKo@N@LIgWlsDOck@HiQTo78NZ0TYal2efZZAti47eq8BmfZd0Sl@vowrfGfsjoUOV6y6z0YYwvCEGz2bPVSBWuA0uNqwuNcumjzekxBA7EEq4KEDChZfCXKFZV4rZ1jtTFDIGn5/K4gl24Dg1I5ORtRUzrKPR6vCoUNLw5fLy0BPRYOWxTPWX2OLOULOiGQ6Xe76mVqFbsoa6LajdOeNKpr1sfv4aaDy1R8PgTgS6HeFGIseOxxjbujcz3UDi10aTr41Lh93CE8twoZ8fEaUoKuqMOUZrwWYocRUtfczN91vLCizaRSHEpuWN3TUCXCO5gnregHWxtYm4AnSOHER3VZkY7ineKwWCAWiZ7Lm873q5NFVvwIYE27B16JlXMv6F0T0cPXwNSZ5avkkfywv2eGlCA8Ne6r5I7NG43fw43OsI2Lds1yeH9HlTAfU9KAX2XE6682Vp6Y5Ax7DnzTdwm2hSf1ahut137UKpL@nwWFnrY6@HHD58vykvi3mRoryGF0WCjuso4XslBz@WvOPXVRDdu@fhgs454w2d6TKGFE5arM4dyPi4YWF5zu7JJRpSlNjY3oqIcRnLqT6N3j9HJ7GqaKNOYjSlAjLIcRigXAJD4DGh@eeJLXdzbN03Y0rX0BZfl4m5yj22TeiW6PNalRJVVj5nCEWW35xF9eyxOTaXqg6POx@ZYYfx5pHLYXLXwyF1HMXHnRcx1MtQp3uj1GHPi7YbmYaOs3avF04WmdcI5OkRartPwPAEDddD9J3xaKH2FvQq54AVzWAUNVG3u5AK9Pm8fKX0GhlnQbL2TXrfqOsw3QxXONXysiyHosfcFMiC5SYdSIvDfmSx50LE1GUW8wwWp728OePyOGixzK@hW8lS1FWqNwUulyXHcsxgis835I4d17U/T00Bk8R9ry7omQJdK3pTjV0TX8JdEGQ2uODjkESnt2pYgfUeoVYI5YPq7k2VPj9H80a1KeAs5BBniBaty@PAEUNbH3a6Okl1Tt30daS4JRMHadhiUXu1KBgOTyhiSSzOaqfrdkxbZ69JIXdTuLKoLWnb4eQnTpayKdLZhHbiCu8YTSGvVhfUg4E5NKn1BvFa7@LhDuFrJdDExXuV98Q0DWmyZxqrAEYWNGsHnwtzsnOyS@A6oNgEuM4MFQQbVzKGrqsL66HuWe6DnUfvzE@uhwD7Q71v3ou0g7khAVwowxSnmXH54ECF3MGmZECwEG0oWDrH5tSP3ksDPpwaUFHj4cpGZ@Do4Bu0slVrH693Yc7AHTgDc8AWHMe2VVQKhBRQxCH1OP0BrnUajRbWQM@Xg@3a9nw5IIthDMd1e0vj2MO9kLiFZ2l4tsE6fL12mEoPWONDw0oyHZhj4OO@G7gjU6C2VaA2Dmmw5yqeE03V/rxjJTdqtFAU0fvnxf9a3aqvu8FoRF/tkT326YMGFehW1dfJEz22toKugnO9vvjSHXbE0FEMF17Q2dzlbbpjBcYA9wozijT7bscYWK9LdHg@gRQNbjDrG@luWDIWEe6iMyj0ULzeVER6qc37H@Jrf1Wlh@MkrDOIDTf078vGouhuXGGkHxs@G/dDE6ng0Odc62J7dit013PlxdgKZkjnFuPEA5lsoB0Nq9IeriFYKYnQRfEzdhiuLVhJpVR4RUFVMGUQEJRV0S4uz5prYprGHkt5g@Eax72IPa8syXBdCh3isuYGH8F9gXQWFtQslaydwbjvX@dtbMy5C9IKPlZr5HRd6ty4K3QLuhO@VpWgaku4YQ3ebRA/xuaNEwP5G2cGKJxiC7prwasNL6iV8crhIdsa@exJhN7KeaNwnQ2omVcnt1jZTJfriWHFdM0eG8dH0@tkMtCvQXjtQ38uGDjfi8PAyKdZp814kuP2gV8LNpkBR7CrdKWl62CWV3/cvQkfPDL7Oi6KfWAFuHxwCVXQ9rFs/cxrcX9xrPvWF8eQs1XEhnvw2ZyZN796Em1L8D3U@5Zxf6Ei4kSGBRyuPWSvBfJHp@t1cTqwfFx3ExtuGHNBkmNEjFTXBhF6CeTVwef4@IFZA2Jb2pZCLxsgdkdT3PkzpaabxoatgA4ghu9VWtSqVU43JuJ0PByN/fC1PA10Zc/8AOuQsTP/1ALkwgvgmmSg28HyQdi50UQQpML@bmZcHmWFfGjZbp98WJIJyF0BsVDOXUI4d6DnfYLLRjxnCSXSuN9w7g51foHJbf4LqFsTF6g7VnDzAEYQ4BKS6I2ZYZ2CewrywAN8itufF4NwtLxEHsx1cvF20td00UBhh@7YM0w0xmdEzEvkIXZzN1oBa@Guejzj4nReszFcG5oRGOylTcNwnXEgeGPnRu5fuJH7V/CcoLnqJqkv7j18mp6vdbpO@HWCZHSS1My0cnb7CjFZDshSq/nlInQk9t9lJ9wc0OWqrwmzg8fwGJQt33WXqSBPptBRLGPm4@Fd08C5rNfG8ch96Dou9C4jYHzDA5Ptx15YZbA8IAZ7gDuOoRy6r43mkKJd0akw6UEfmR2oR3tmepO@hSG@qwf6iq6FDntRlSw2vZYmLLtjeh/R8aw58yqtcTFB980JVQNWEwZra0JgGEx6xaGmhbawMLngj1zXYU/KPWV4KQ9v5hLA2unjzWdvRVz0vaB6L1WlFrP6@IQtXTC77MCAVXn1zI5rs@cNC2Ici01U655l@tID3H9O3Qo5IoA05d/IK4o38oqZFgOS6Ynu05nj5VrBDKUy@RzrUga6Z7g4aRMablgyMrdp/DXsOF5HzmazO1DwE@BMujEOj3h8XbLsYWdIHysVgLnaPDAhmi4uWDucOoE@uV6ZbPAl3GY@t8wo3pwdsSVs1AWSegLaRXq5Anel9KwRfVDOu3IGl64UERzLNF7qONDk0nKZDa8u@EPepEfUuGK4da650IFQSae7jZe2mMV1UyCI2KYQDDxQw6XgphHa6KiLJUP646GJ856LEwkrRU7XH9DMusuneGMm6plCeOoa8Iz4BDYm1wk7KyVGRA//x3felaBTbRdy0fEPwKJeP6kMiR97Tvh6E0p74vpBz5o8hnTjGvNVbAOzlYcg8GItAE0bqzIBteeMbTYg0J9b9DPsUjVKoGfoCoJN2XJgCqZzItDDuCbXc@Sy7UPSDp6tGphdIdyLjoPlwoNoJ1EMFr6XzOnN80BcUahIrGAnhVy4xnBZ4Z5GHADkJzcQRj59SyP/yf6Dx0fiyFeW9kM7A1x7f00uW9jcrpbkuVGij3RvbmqOrYXqWn4g3TlUhN0H@yICrChvNnovwAsnlxZeK4cio/M0JX2l9oK@ZrBc4Lt/9PBBZrbxjqR2B547NNPz3ruHh1ncx/Du4VLv@dD3oHX03MnK4Pt7ipJeQr7h7sxVXHJJTKswHZmgRQIx3mdnY7xWiDLckdk9mo7M96CTRE7tv2H0hZWZfKSfWH1shaS8sqBoQyVlsZBLzy3/BSXZ9OL3qvo8tkbILQ36kthr5QoJlBA0ydOWSwk3TU5flVaIHE6Of75AinydWudPdJV0/5@aMEVRVpXzod6DeiX5lZW1CLBsitN2T95gNtQMlREhdhICoCrBeu1i5aIwBNYt4QNHzENHMHZWrsy4CUHsXFja4E9NZ6o7AkpLocvIjaWMD825uZp4scgJHve8dNoqXm9NUgY1RsV85M157e7e2Y88Dph7aHvn0VPyRPdB41mC0ZzDOJMsPhJwvAZP8Vo1cLHf9YBTs36iP1pO9xVyqHtd15lO5poKzuJiV0cProzDoI0CmbY1sZbxboONzzxZvhIkioOtkHenC3Le/MEYYYDLL/@6osgyPfYE34rMrFcImKTQpE/xzKx5r6P9mPQN7JdFcEgv1aoemBNcMcBGKZcpp0v5d@EG3l5Mr2aXN/mVbvDL3RDfNT90xD0Vyg0I8zf4kbwYez9w7dOBK@7qnnlDcdyU9PINSS/P8ZvwJGY6exWaVwutuBI8fC2ltyMz8HKjgduxcgsi8uIGypXD7YHu0fUHfTdcPM/sy6M6HUcN@aH@0pxvwsczPmAOxrhkfMlEWgcEMdPpW@zgNXLHDfao7QZtId4funyu2RrdHY@usBI8o/4Kd3oflDL31Cd3cMfPTD5colzi2qLl7quEKRKPMOEZg/ePdqJIHx9K6lyMs1R88GTBGffEBY8P59w8czJZpW0Jk1XKy1KfWayPjnIL0W7Wn528Zl8F9GzA6uL3yi6X8Z13D6@3TtQUBsHQjnze1R0zwtN1A7pJKh6Hm4xmg6PvDygBRHxsyYIu6EUsC3D4UruNh5a026uo5Mj8gA4sQ19JAnOCYj0T8MOzgcxJbhCEn@2gQVY2APc45tqHo4HlTELLcOaOa91I6iM/yvEOObTdUxIpPHPNJ@yxIIh@Yjo3b2oSytrNHbI23@sulBM7/D98rSqiOyt67zum5y2DOTCke5HlPTW9BOLdwwhgme@u7eIgadcaD5d506CZzDIvb6FhXw1kLfPAs@uPB67nLPOMKqZSuWOuRL12g99wCtraMo9Or7fMec93lzk/HNuBhUJa5PnIHUPrichqz4ukt/pmvdkUK@LMikfx@gMvPe8CnGLojn0Q7yw7fRVU@MgKFhyvlDd1w7OATUd03Kt433XJF6xZOucz8XJlKb17b@azOE48xplCujtuZly1U2o01V5Lvi@tPrUsJzzHGl7xnR2ztO@5DrOl5@d9okOWlmC7r9tWevVEqPqamVBkc8yfnGjLWhkw/HvzJfredBJLzk9sumU3tO2qkIG@YaTDT0X4dPWlos0NCrAlIyuWvc1Y9hf3hroxP@S4cNZCNG3kz5j4nGbhHT66s3P0/pMHof0L@rATxRAdj67eZau24jUaV4ZR6AHy0iE@BX@gQ99FR1AE3D19ZQbt/Z0HTyJ2PACRHIoSz3ibG2iK@S5JdT1fH5ZjCfJhtE/pLrQ9NM840f2p6QrjOFOsv1um5q/cPXD1jKiboedOdrpWG4/M4HDs9dIrN7Kqy5Wdwwer2Oq7UTYP33n47hfvzbY5PbKGRBZV@F9pGaIiyled1OtO2nWn3HWn/HWngihfkflWSIPicq00RlS@jlu5lnb1ekLV6wlVrydUjRM65yRfdwpjZBvFQRyYP4rfz4ZHQrGDFdh2dl@MvpeQSjnAhdOLn62a35uPB1an1vHA1nW6Dx9gz8/JWrj3HTz4aDd9uNsfz3W0nLGJ2/XZh2uC2jpEU6sp@TLZwm9CVYgi0zjxQ3pldnxeFFmDrJ@FO9krFeWCrNUIX@FJeJZAfBo2O9EZEONZtJApIhwrZD0An/VoHzyhnygh54QOsAoGHvkJNlGaPxGkGp4UAGlaP3uy/2Tv8Gjn6OlhQ25dhCcJRLlwHIgtOq/kltblIfNhuYFiy853pydY2BAd/S4FDsz6Ub4IfpJpMWu1hazNMsVvYZj1M8eRJHqYgiRcQPoEnsVGfVGyBCeGO8oxraDwHI0KO9eAHs8AdcRQ8zROqLQKkZdFPNJ9H7IV@l/9qhn1xa/iVfC7eBhxeCQ3CLJ91@2GMfomef0VxXhvZ//B04M9EiVwRjWnVjcY1Mp5dmJ7eFgbj0cr2PTUkWQYJAl1Vasl7yWhYJJiklTo8Rf0tHQ82C0Z0wMenBGG3iCpdYofSjAZV4r03z6WLpIi7sZIA2wySlQSogWap4SCR9sdAZGQuwf77@0dEEz/3l3qjEWEKMgRbs3/yx902fdGohOxoi8CesNQcYPa8l2rW8EDMQyTJHKKGp6q0yV4Ghw7M4KYE/rtDkp5dNRo7huBaXpKETd/ikd0tMXs9A2sOcoB5kOy74LQUy3iD5LE31XiOHrqHtD7KT008sp5iml6Zhn7/iE76TRGTUkv@rYBzqqCokmFDcu38EwNrIeeO/auNBLc506PDxXJDn4sET/JqNNP50Bix07Ajl8Lj2RKAIWKMa/KknWaWPahHX4OMLm5Bo2kY4K@T3zHAtkyqJCPgIJxRrPCzlwRhHryWpAIdYWaBNQm5wCZ5jvEA@yJMNrDc/SannT5a78i9asEzAGYvxqaJ/IdsH0ttPXA/HVmfiYhgUrJa99XidMynyA8XzXMAUsI17N@9jP8fiqfWleU47Z3kknm5So8lGqe5Mmt9aYgrDfk2va6DgUZvJg0oTlLG7kT8@6g193vS02eBwE0J0kbZ2dnyXsbT6xneVIQupZaeDGZXmgF7cXkQlNKL45HSqEhvpi0@FIte9xqNlrkyZMPXrVfpfnJCR13TAGB7T7mlRyfqJTJ2VZBSxyX8dtqkMNj8hKu4x7BPzW/7M6ZdTR3ekC3SZ4kmk382Clf5IHtJVvwp5ziOVyMZzTqYl3car16lW7oejCZEsuyRn63C7c7IClVTR8SaGq3oRGxABJp0jctRLjyw0mPTHbMfn@8p0@t8b1gWyyKJVGdY0ybDz98P7yq7z99SshT8vTpy4MVbKyVyaQEoUHNk8jxAciE2QmptPV8Ar@O9pefrV1kz560N//yk6FkruHrMb6@evEQzYdK/tba2q07d3K5rKqqzPzkwye/uLOzk7ubzT9p5Ldygry2@Rd/vramqpuqtNbyfaWVbBwff8Crco4X//L7yfaTJ1/0/br2Xz9@VVfwUYTHCSmSMl4aUcCIzxLcCsnnyZteiZcJBa7ElP7aicj9bI0o9a3if//m4xeJIFFXpfc9eAeJF4lCKcGMYACbFtlOEvXEJoIVLhJTqVargbH43/89hK@/C3jQZ7oJj3o@wlWYJupCjQY5T9QLYFBUFeL9Pz/@eC6FwM@AldSgRQqlyG0bGGKjweeKKr/VgmuDXpscHkUkyJIUwTnBIDBdopRuK7fRYoEFXg68cOComcDvQz7eJuKzgwz0CRnxvfqadHdTgEscSYqiNhXlNrBf4dZGrSZAv0Kbrablb@MxkWnaG/bdwCXm7fcXrsT7/7dcS9FU3//nuQ7IrmWYnpvlEoW17ed363XIuVbXNuoZeoXNjba8Yol33W3gOkeDsWe5@MnJ6gP8eEqdl0sqn81mtw/aEIRMJliYwmQithEFYR@0TrBLbBPmgg07dGRUCVcdeUKLxO4sVGSdwZHnyQa0ltbz1XCJPbz@6j/@1bf/6pv09216/2c80cnpWj1pA4BOoOHU4dquVIx6na97/FkT7XWgNrlSqpSk9kUztdGotw5AwH3nPJnXkuTQnmYhE6pKmulmg4av02jrYfRorydmznXmUp93Cz0YMHWAd1hSJBHlcy5fcakRcgWOS0SrkITGSb0l4EBmTWgohXxLYKEa21A5vFos8@1WQlifAk9SW3U1rz4m23V2kcG6T1xMjaYWooyE6a3P8jbzmdnq806JehSsPoP5vHBhmsqQM18KZc96lNDttcpaqVKoqFK7vvqqzkLgRUFN03ziJ04S8VUlIR1G5ZmIKXPO7dl8TcTVQiICJgthXwPHJRq1RstsQRsJ/8suWl1aQeGroUlt86QK9KFqgtpv87ICrW27HbHzLbjW4Ef/cMVWfK5Rl9CZgly/1khF2VA1KX@rsKdiH3z1Ip7QqGcojxRa9YyIvFIQrwBx0KsQo9PpvDQ6IKPoekc3dCXQx/pEn@pBZ9yZdAJjbOCXhMkTFPTaYRl4mpt3S25UJKKQ0PLKeuI2UrimlvGjvKCllEpaWdWKilYsaEVZLeW1Ulkr5rRiERBqRVUrl3OqqhWKWqGkFQpaoYwfPgaYAsBoiKGY18oal3jVWCMHjL9NSCa6mpnXXk9FytHwogYXb0FwJwkQocbGcZZL/DNcdUVVyAZ0kzI8QDakRqLSH@RwV7fGfpYjCRD7zlqvNhqvNsh8bQlhmuEltrdbGeHiogHmajX8b9ZjY5VezARZbV1kMpvP6iANPas3MoDyWYhSFAhFKrbrpLVJveLYwuhC/81Wqw@@mZHfR5IRaCJeQCIym43NmrtLb5G2TqEFsWwupHx7m5LaNoSqr0O3kM5k1gVhrQGoG2EHBcBIkGEWAROApUCUOTv7OW@yuQlM5mLzon7R2Ly42NyE/yZ9XoRvcL3YjP7JnJssuNuxnb5m1zzoHMzMv4V8qtmQ6k2pGfKqFthFqY4uotQEQx3eANfQ1FILe0eUg8TWv8y/mJ09YxdMckuEVHOJDbKRwEOQtMQGl3h@@en/jHfz8tMfokxL4GdWuMQZIVxC2igT6kZfZRDsHjrkIbscMOMdWdEFHeoP0dFhDwc1ZUl6LpKKQNXllFIqpEXs/ttur427TEXyHEABbK9vQiOKeC/h1VKBb2eUqUoSm3yhSNntL1y7ksnkv3qulotJpo3jNsnnvu8/nEvlLJ0AXFVlRVDO6@xQW3bq@C8su/7VL6y6uMR5mWAZpQgrFy4BZJSQJNAiuUR9c4hr9vCLHQJ@eu2k9oHwdEfYdYcjPaDqOo7lgahQ29@rlct1VKPM9Se08Wzc3YCnAv@9NcgEafYAtNmrGUMQ0Zs9La82UWt9RwftHRid0HmBvwcv8UeODPwdvMAfOXqJv4MAf@RhB39HL/C308Hf0RB/d17g7@FL/D3t46/5lqYpVX5dP@lOuvCfvFyfrJ/RssooZeVifcKzMkts1ZtvQXH6ySrZTr7VoKNC@XKrgb4t8Hgr8KaV8FsU/tTP4pJK08ASN40Ur26pfLrKqgyYhZYrp99iQzIV8hbRa@Vqp6ZWw@Bx0JrjxjbR8qMvAqbYHtyKmsaBEK2cdz1BJ5YPD3DIaGXF9ZI//cYnnyRrtaSQpKe358BN6CBQhwKBFULmqlZNeQuUmVeCWWGpS5npt@jwW@UtQjBPb@HopeulhmnLSXbZzhJpPLa6kuVK@O1bqz/ScRmgxJKPh7PpHnOTTkznRDKd8VB6aY300UjyTcMzAzyxDWhiEpwA1CyciJTU1QNdeuk6Jg5zSYE7tBFjkh1AnOIlPl1pt1mQdhtSVbUymIdwhIvlImVt5iGXKdt0Up458lKikk7XNXquqSDktBzkPp/Gs4nr@chRKYNdSb8FlUdEk33WKgFEqXCJGllX1hXZlg1Z6SgdMFhE9og8kAdKFxThtkJkk8hTeUrkoat0wWTCTwaTJfeI3CeyIzsACL5gCtpygKYevPrw6wEiD34WLqTqKLJBICIb1WX6QSlED6bzNnln4PpBdtTkGiRJ@Ofm8@fPcdReLFgt/LxAg3/@vClttNRyiYjIGMR243kz2eKbPB4@q5ZzpDM115rPeRDvZJ7VN7oQyGcj2aompGZTCqlUzVHCv7hot/ce3W23JZQzmsSsZ7Yz0Elub9eg0wxfW4l6datZod1w1BUnpM2tZl0T0FzIQI@qghu5b0KVZKXM57xmiOFdX6MF0Hp@@hy0ydQp6pSnJ/A6jQzvN@HRZtom9ZZO32/OWakBLoSVpPeXYFgwQKodbxpLjvAH5fyf62/9y/o/fErSqUYrnTq72EzRK50iaZJKp9NnF2cX4bOeTqVCS2oTfugAdgx0dlFHIwU6A1MjlW6lLy6YGzxTaQDHHwTZrNOgM7AzkmBRhr/wQS0EDCQ1c2GpSqXmYWYgkAuAYMFwvmoRKnZIp8KrCXz@Ob@56RnnzSpl9jm5TBL886o@m8BpNieynAbWHZ6OLThkXT@no93pqoGfnlvvNJTWX3yfnoC@laZA@Vy1qmwQZlFzarWai2zFUrVaiizrqVT5@lWXt5QCKKK5XDpdrYJlK0IrgxXCNsirDKmRJjxbt2@zSErq@XmEU8sVMjJOnFWrUUx5iNb0dYM2eNBPz/Yf09PDgWPkEwQZQzj0n5Lp1wdOdDuV5Cv87dup8PuyWzvp27fVsnx@HruMRuCkLDi1213La7fRXTs/59s8nXMp58Eul87PFbmcUZIE2HLqEX4kFBm4oJBbap1Gi@xZzRXBO9mcKAUFOzeddm6FEh7ej2yebzp8ulbjk82mk@TRL5eTwTOnlSHDrK@ukv@XriSfrPKJM1qySqnI2CtfRWdUOoHTkLOLBKUtksunU8CZ06AfXCTw5yETp12bls@nqzlZTpxd8AxYKZcZdJrkCqlSphz@amtpUgfhl/1QgtcyuY3ixjYOZfr0mly/kM9Xz8yaclE7Myv4NZyLqhF@FRI3Wpu3b2tlqK2SnCB3x3jcQ7bJhZ1EDQQhlKPh0eSSyQy5dZvDXeheslLdprSmlPIkkawyRyEJnQ0pQbVL6kZeKWGRcFYPj08AYZBTaLGtkTVOpW98cGVWmGvomOASMUt@3Z/rwkW6pEP6eJE@jjkQi9j0IjZh/vRpGDGQy67QN7bSsHSUInIx44vNuWh5jbWnJHkwNiwc7XzyYGd37yirbgokod7b2c2qh0/vJBS05md26q2h/WBv5@7jpxDgyYO9ncO9d/bf23v6BNx9cjq74j4t6tniHm7OtMR@St7nPvJe6qapm2PTbJ@Ox6cvyEeW1bagyu0x5M3te8Q325ClkT7LXhVuw/L1jz7SvRG9yOX3vnz5vV@6/P1vXP7@ly9//9s//fTbX4b7B3B/g72/8cflPD5/@umv/@Hl7/0@OP5nuP8M7s9@@ulvf8xuav8R3P9lzu1H4T0Hx24OcH3tp59@8/s//fTr34H7d8P7O9fvX/ts@f3tL62@Mdw3//BmmG/8e7j/iOGKYL/xe8wN39fgf4/Bff07l7/5H9j/L8IfGn//8jd/hI/Q8qvf@Yv/cvnJf1LV0l/828svffPyS59cfumrl1/61@rlb/9bRZ5//OHlt//kb/70j/7mT/8N/f@APv/oTf6X3/nVv/5f/vp//es/De/P4P4PYPrsr/8TNOO//5Pv4f@bf/L3f/Y9/P9Pf/D3f/Ktv//a/0gNv8MM//i7f8yeP/7kyz/@0m/8@JNPVzy/fOPz0zdw//SfweXN0/kmeN4kX5/X5dOfKz3/lNKYxQI0AJT7y5e//RUg3t@EPuryyz/AXR9wr/j/QFUozA@Y7f8DBvV6ntFHBhPc37r88jfIB1hK/wOUEvzJBx9A7/RB2OV/8MEHYQl@Ff3A/QPqyK7FgMwz8p35fJXM4KAavktI4/nzFs5nL6Cmlp9@@hvfp7aEWanTuUrs9UtqKbMBattGuRxPYm4i/FdilInF4PmS5jhONYz2q8i6FmL4KjK9y@99fPn9f335vd@5/N7XsNMXcuXsTlZQXjMRDID5N4BDwMKbwCEgRN/O0BFcIQNm81zCvUjb54RUIR9aSWvOwE2p19uowI/Ao1LZOMsKW02QIWmOL2hY3MwE4qgiqLcyW2sSUfSstqHpACjlGBypONtyLlPc0HWJa59LuPGJnJM5o6QwSEkNy5J54doxKcQsKWrstR4hiLPBJTKY3AwVgzYi4SyvkUkmzMkkXCyA7gA02aDGCWFTPBPqPeEmdE1B9J8ZJxzJUMmIXviNq8hIDWG4aD1CEe4wI3mIKzObRaIiI2HS2gZzoUstaOQ50Jno7GxmUqujAWc/wOsO6Ci1WgYD1liiwMrSVy8Rmp5MpgaZx9AsTLZdQhSTOxQLhKzRcqhNWMAM4qtHZZLh0ImmJlOq3YUIa5O76JBB5BTt8@e1eqk2qSO6V6xQMpPMHZomRFbLTOqvwF6jOCEcl7j7CpJSqmUy9RJGiJlkdYRzs1hTeZo5mnec52cVAW9cbLe1TcgtXinxbA5tDQuMQeMzM4NGQAxy8JxXVP45n1NlHoCbmY0wb/QfGem9QUt/jcYbRsnyjjGvUWSk/XzjeQhIISE2QRBFkcCNC1u2yDbZ4lipZTI0MfDKhIVIiYUSR@xAaElxGVrrrNgAPzjTL4ESVc1VQSmpEnTyDA4/HEZXS8nc@gRXwp2RUFCWw69hXnA6wORkjTs718OVcus6uQCnAocQNM7axue@MLFYauvr61yizmv8Y7oiICNJxDuu0PWO0PaoelUhfKHMo7NJF3@yUnyIOxyyHDVXMZvk8uPvJ3JyMcGtJ@mXhwmLiNzKsHt7e4PcgmKl7zm3CV1WKGQ0N@cmWDFuZjK8CpHWXbBt0CLMUGzcM5Ko4R/cE5TcoAt@onuWn@WylPFl4SXWEuhNHj9@HKaXOjyrcRloh6qmoB1ng8fjMQQ3u7jyIpsVxayYzYZvkb6pgxgaROobvsV1LHoyrwYqxRJ@ctQxBlgu3KtXr4A2OCyLyj4OclMjqam5EvUklAwmuOBPH2Y5dhKDbU@jdcVqrsyxYRWiFHKEpChFwJUmuIA2BTSe5tgqPEZe0ZVKqqVSkkJCjYkpAGNoCgpyKrZSme65IvnighVSNm/FAVM2sYFLQuIlwix9qVI@HXnuPia7jx8@3Ht0NGrVWtDb0G/cmu2R5xqm76fQc@fRXUa/armQxvl3zP1RRUXeye1VZCTkzP7dg/3DCmFlFlZeiuakStdThCVTVrjEaPT@ZsLD6RXP5PHTTi5/iM/KrDBSalmDoIk6lzBM1MqAUvEPd5UcmH0k4Id@/447ISk5y/NZpYC6dBoXPEByftEdEzy6kZ0XAfwB13OKkGNMef1MmJtgRIc6OVA5ZhAUaiBauRQZisygFAsI8Jh9/Ezj6od7R4D56DFRVFkkB27HgkTVPyATkRDgAgfu0HSzwgUNjTzpyBq6CGHXbNPpB4N1/KAs35T5uQJab8hZ/KmaBk8lV8gq@WJrbc0@ExBPkxLNGa5WvQDrmYBl8jZchHubI2@DE1zCBeHckemQcAZm/3GVkS/uRCYpSP1h4PFKHjhDmsMpqRAfN5q/qljq0NQWJ3e5xNqHHwakXt97dFfYv4dDFpMBida6ClZXHIiUdLpjz6S@fUK61nsW7pIQu5Y/svUptGMosI06lEiAM@@Ji4uLHuDcv0fUukqtLGwXnxcGdemA@WKicwR4dI9L3I5Gabji7Uql9krJFSFtlcorTVU5cOA2JC5h9daA3OhqpQ2J/XinllPkjMImBlIOSfM8X/UhUZpWkja4hMLz8NI0jaNtiHAVkyN0NdsruVYTQjafU@hiNg4PtNcnNTW@QtjJrRmsJjNY9AEP0g88Ikd@ReYX2qKeAbKCy7vpp02j8Ur59m0Nx6q0nBznndCiIRdQp@taTqOVdM90AqQzgr6tRK4YTpdCPlsJzjYD0q2BOdHEjNN42XJ5/Ly8T8YAWcgBUzytqAqbOsupuQRPEBpZpVaSuUQjATyAa7SAF/w//ms1uNbkX@4fiqXRqHET4KXzd@iMMPQdXhz30H08@z9@PJy33vgfPnYfPnaHLvyht3yITL46@1erC9ab/yFvRfZarUJScTITSFQGWSUP1n/89sf/8Jv/8R9@66siXqEtdvjHb3@Luf/ur@PzW9/@h2/90j9867eoy6/9w@/@m9DrH3/3D8hdYALTlzrS5uXXP7n89I8vf/jZ5Sffvfzhn6J1/v/pvwu9PvnWzBHM6HLl/y3yt7/2v/3dd7/6N599/Hff@uzvfudPfvzx19WS8uOPf@Xvfuezv/mzrxGw/@RHX/nxx1/721/55Mcf/zLAzf9/8qOvRl5fih3BDC7X/@AOeLn//7rxQgaN60/okorN8ITPOt0d0VDKudYe8LgGaW1Gh3/WAXqTbW4keHpLjUcClAKLufF137R7Iu45qPGbo7omq/xmeIJ4nbxnOtiHhOHr3VrXNehnwKtd0cLPseM2PhYul@OrroPn/NWi1QcgaaTP@rVTuj2/atb6Ip4o4zm6DcE7bncq@sEUhETDtV2vlgSVNwly9nuWa1MqBvNO13VQhnVqJqhZOMOwpWm5CuRPHLmjLTVfFIjQUGQQPPFWStku9IPeFvS/FTW7Zm4Vi5WuaNim7m3lK3n0NuLVJlt5udIXP3j44H4QjA5AYjL9YCtXhgB4Khuen7RVquTzwFJ4PtOgMbbw@8ZMwBDW1qA/NvWuAG9cjOILaqlVofHXasnklqaoglLR5BIXZnZWYE7VEXJKYUuuBPPFSPZsy3G9LM/hZ1jjWsAKHCj1nJzblOBNoO5xZQyIU3WyY/ZN7I9ozSmb0ghpAowAqoOxA8b8ptQBowXG8qZkgXFc1xR5UxqD0ajnFHA1GJVgbRCrW4M4MWcZTHYWySU7UM5C@aLiuI55wVWyetY6ozVX6fV6FxtnmZmFJLbpanj1ymr4M9DbzgQGB7V9IejZzllsrQozDFyFjLOCNfMEF70HxHMWLhGq8Gq@xFcb1Zm9WOCrrQtue2h2LR0/rt2Uz66HKoBIyLAmIKIm4S4qnusGlY7Zcz1zBqgphQiQJeg6QI6/iKNryhjj2fXoCnNAk7NZucbl2bFd4ziMiX5scllcuTx/wRlhcXhm94JFlK1kI0cWlJINViNWaOLZMy6xcfCeVq8D3Z7limoun8urWqGQL6og/pZzhXwJyEYuyHlVBeaRK5fKxQtotZL0KkG/Vkd2z6LWXKHfK0jpFXaKZ6NF0q8eWfZZSRMY@0mlqyAuJV5xiVsH76n1@upxuBSoEu@pQr2m5ctg0tCkalSoUlVB1QRNERQN/68xqPh/c3gV/io@IZSmckd4xtEjkOJBgXHIAzymJXDJkevSfW93TGMFxO5Ap@cp7Xqu7/8TYO7ozjHzumuxA3Vjr/s6ftXNH1rBYAXE09HQcnzcPPfPhWFv2IEEIrdnAHfg4dmuuwygSJ4@gcfB/jv3j@L38lw/jI@oh8JhZ9RDiKO9nd37XIHcefzo7pVXPkSXJw/27h3F1iLzjYLmYxS/uPfgwVVr@Mo9fnrQG7se3ty9x09zs0fshNsFuRxci0CxM0USPtCKIh6qKmSN5IuRQeFwp@LtXJncDo35wswoo/F9thfS8uPNjGw7bYU7ijZI6gS7gI5J8CtYZpcO0dITG8ORDaVY5rgRcdxTUpRJ17VtHb8231sDx4Huk45poppu20iJGPWp69ndU6trroFoDHGUFfyyNyaCuw9IhmNjgBGAloTn/HbxO/C4vqJjj00yHpGVjvBCJzR6Vn8AksapGwFwHV0ncH/eC8Kb81dws0PA4qBu13zs6@Bcgtt5jAMwiRLP7/L8fb34jKDwNMiWslrF4YM838eJbdsPuo2NMSh4a2u5ElGb8q5MV6lNdUmRqp0aUQrndXcbhxQ22ma/VvHzBWULe@SanNlOuP59s1Tl@ZGvO1lglNmKj6MpjvWMGFWnAvr9aET84gYhTfO8VEIdctfTdKvfbE62ctVkErsMSmWVv/3uD37y59@6/Mpnlz/8LRQEyV3XM3RcXo8aOaH6daiYi3RASC2X8qWyppaypXIpl1cK@XxWUbNKsVQsQ3JlpaQUSvmyki3lyiDB5crgmy8XQ7VekjbIjo0jeVmmuksbFUDvGPi16006tiQO6lyCrdohL1N6miT02D4mvAlheLLj9E0bcOCgYEB36W5YNei/iSITrUgAs04Mkrh3b1e@d4/n76AFlzPuyjzfRUu@JMvFOzxvUp/dEgqpvMvClPAIRz5gFlm@A1U5ZgjwqwU8P0DLXgFnanjeQsvuzr17GE8PLSqGB7Bj5sMsdmQpApiDFk1jCF7E2ABsh8WTowndQwtGiT73mM8u@PH8O1Fy0OeAgTEE96Oc7uzw/D6z7Oygzy7Ndp4l9Ato2aEXz3tggXbG830w9D1o4TzfASO2Np43wGRMdXDDL4zjgfdOoPP8lBUPFhDPTyi0bhzzfDtyx2jeC1OTx9KtUIvCcr1NLWX88bwaJRrBtNii8XwutuQgb/fvv6cPgq7ZZ9fUY28Dcnr/PtD3ZLx3r/POO51@v@NNd/beOUCv3d37INlMx16n3wkDdtpwuRBq976qHw@nVy/I9X67XdHtpV5faLdzunPFqz1tm5hCCPUCUhZefYxo2N4Fr9377W19yYqnCUXYRkYzhHcHrztDeN/RO8wruqgXfU86Hb4KzQD0mWaKQxUMVy1h8zwGxu1kh7rhuVW0T2pEpqv8p42C3KpSDzIEHUquXqB/L4VPHQfe02fTxqQmt2qTWlFlw229FN@cqHmLz64Nt5RyvrKmbylqLjOp4AEDbi9JkoKyRVLK7Y2XJPUovaWCJrXGN7e2BL6htLYKxWfI5Sr42FKVUiUnqyTNrFqxAmHkpEwIPtKNYmurmK/MAheLGV1SK8UiyIBQPgFIEh0c6W6TVOrU1I/TaUw6HSmF/NCMkynNtFXtpSbZSY0lkkzT1UlNqbJTool8BVsq1cVPD4wNPKKGMKR9QDgBVQpXy6V4pVziIQ2ShGs1cfyOFc5ZTi5dnJ35Z2fNi5hVSmCajVW//8Wj46OjD4BbgWgyZUN89XCU94lnIs@Llt2/c39X3H8c2fCrAuI9lJJdT9xFHrfgw8TlyOkItCnxPvTvoElHbhAm8Fxb3KPr0kHUjjyio33E8ORf8ej@Ap7DgXvKYoZAfhWlOR2PdsCPLlhdotfqYNK7JEVTRfT0KZUs2vV6rV0bmsNRMIUsRqG@QOgXCWZo9n2WdvoRmL7pERr8rOe5w9CjXZMvoAecJCaCQHZA0Bt7WcDYrhFBeT50u8/VjFHFZfrkTu0Ooqm24d2pmjXT81yPB1WWr/a2nNrY8fWe@cT08LyK/cfrIPHgcS@pHjHT66S5h9C7qGBdCHWPOLM0PhoPU7pQ76QXnXBmJHbAYkp9Mcr@Gc4MQMp5/qLaq5HUMwB9AXZvnaS64p009LlQYndIOw1O8vPe8x5RSSFXpfpQCnFBE6QlhSWgp2v1L4CgxlAfk0oFUhNW@TFgxcgAMdQG9dHTI@uiatRskhLIJE3LKFft1xoY/BwfmwJIGoLQOG/hxMb7qCS8GEPnWYfmXp0m9Jo/7tDv8BC5o6hyoToBN6WYqw6gvvVnk6pXG409s2qDNZwKITTHehXKFooQ0Lw8T11@5eP0ppCvMbcqRXWOskdbbNcmVQdPUAVKqWk18Mg0cnI2XwIJJ1/MggihFrJKIatlc1mhiK4gP2TzWXAEfQykpJSd4gnhs/JEFpWsYirZlPzc6j5PZ49TMpQDLbx0NnD3nPGQoAtUGVIrtcNbT2fUDSiirkv0TYESLzCZKuYLyn5ARlZ2QDEdmLrNAqQFom2k7PUUAq0fjUd7jValsjcZfRG8UsKLrUKmKGdeptPV1Fq65psv6LTRHQsIRIfCRc5Esz9aA5oOp4uIPx42oNbBpBTVSqPRwbwW5awma5BNq33e3@TrfCsrrxUUqLMLOiugEMZZ5idIQHLiZm6jNioMtgl1qJTVKkf3kCTIHW9MZ2y0kiqUpfxGXmazJAwFNwpZJJYtSTWjTULJVDJZVJPJmXadTlZxRnqNn00QUp2bridOJYFlk@RtNV/Y4kEA5Ct8WeUBbMZxMZVEjlK@QXZ109c9nEnicMyC5EBnP@Muzi4269xE5PaGlm3pWRBoDfygnWUci9w91@tmScfqk54eYFsWuR3I7X5F5A5B4TOpqbGHHzUgLDw9qQWDtUKEFTrNFgymIP56EH5KZx0D8bor1BLBdxTVIgR5izvEgz421Wf4Kz57uPMYf/e2E7g3hWy/BX5lcC89e/j08dPH9@hhDrM91p/n2uaIRDegTMR2NVGlg/@4RAOiwaxVPscS8G2ciCfSGp5SQDKiINbpSRjbLJZmeCaTtEbI590hk9msP2PvJu5SBdQcPVG9QVp0jbhpob5O3tNBoNwiSahy3Rs2VFVrNdQiiCXQdTVkBqqqShVS0U7QLdd1oO/JGSR6M1PH8y6@QKZTPSNEWb9N6v3MuqxOEydtvlDW6JEM7boiH5O15O0N/FS4QBInx2t1dSOTfFLRMsm7SS2XOEk11@sZZZqUyEZGnfZwhRoui5KSAKeaG7e0jeTTTKXUz1aUDD5VeFaSRFhLbLez2@myz1FKJomFAl4r79R2@gc70SL/nd16SZ2G53QknrX5UjFMYnMdikzNPNteCF8HWegZTuFeqbefZ73/Ni6BT1aTibMkSSQvkheNZAtQNxrxsS@11iz5uKAvXACh5QoknSDp0FYsJ/xUvPrgreR2IolT/MT3XwFB03qgzTo6keELz1VgMgnHjRzccYDDvSBG5fM4gZ2Qno/8D9WS9nD/sXPXu2dyieba@ZqLixNIlWcoefLKefeLoMdCbSVJs5aY1HLhDLBSrwvKpoqnsBVJBQSAnlIQ5PM642R16lFQwefyK9/JTTZLYFdlBeyqms@o9bqyASJoYnT56Q8Db0rO9t7beUCSOJ/8kz//vlr8yZ//AV04n7ygc8yqVkwAJBqVQjFxdjY6OwMB8IL55ROtxLX1gC0oJknRy8UNsVohUqlU3hDbUiLcfZlSiko64QuJcDtFIS@kUoqkpje0kpwGn/PwpKuUKpfAGq31oE58Ic@nE3sHVl5Vtje3IGdbWk6trjUavBIPi5P4t2n65QSXKD18fk4IWIx6t9@3VGqSpLANvRLI5ithE95Qw6@ENfK8VsdFjQqeLxMtG9jAsylwHU@ynpE2kgT0bFJvXFQvWhm69oAOfzzbcJpXCqO5hpuZF502HPiZGz79mSa1UgcfrJHN3PjI51MbaUnqdmmfg@s@BKGeYCTbNkm@DvSyIUEqN6KlAuwnCM305Vd@W1ULP/nzXztvn7c/UFW1XC4XFDXxs59tjp2xb3brP4OAT6IzBYGIDKuLxHrkHpuOL8bjDbSjsxzcdmo58TgFYWdKWmGo2CAaPJcYO6iLMfho1ALHJwjIo1bfMbt0tII7QWmaVmubneLXTVGwDQLKSJbqcvTYsHSV4yI9h@lqXt/IUhxkA8@fbrTS3Bn3NnqBbEZA36tyb89QgcMQpDHXaPv22BvRTeApGk5pZcltCAIxvI0nJK4BdJqEfbYAXBj66WtBWZJ9WmpU3iZ4VDqetwiiCPc2BAnPy7enhG7CpZCWA3KCiCA0ndSj24C4WxC3zQK0qWuK5p4BZAlLHQvkgArHvY17gamKByInsTYBoAo85W0oAMhDKkRstcgm0dLkzMpkqrPDHC/w6B7c1KxHpw1yGAyxdaGY4sBVhAMnUB3xo8BIF2ENA9@bc4yQMBxsIV8NlE8MTm0ozFtADpM3RgW4TgdYQzRr5PbtWapqNaubJjRHiP/YGuGgLa0HZ3laAVmkxd8ClgriVCaDlf32ItlBiWdocoHqBHY@ZnUuKOHResFx8H9jokWKvFJV1KOKGQjri7UKA4oMAmOxszo0yGaNKGoxTeLEG5B2gyaKnkUVD000J7dE9YPI8wJS@LNE9H0vYFZH8wPhId3eNe3z4Xlc4D4BBWxMz7wNBjpjBl3Ttoa4QhCHrZHp7QdR6DgUZMWyKXTP8kANpusFo0MaU5qSxmCzQy1pOugeRjVHcCdhPo0vGgqhCbx1PDQwjGeNiq6GCxXqj1yHnjIYIGvCrZxAEcCjIIJHbmCyZI@dU/zoXlg3NPB8iiCXoOUg5WOK6amJrmP6LCwuu@t4pn4clU2WmH2RGMMuUcskRQnNwfUlTowuTQPRBHdAe8Iy7tjmEJJ0aJr0LAa/Ikl9EPrGHZwclx5aQFeDexZ0P44v3WUFLJ1ax5Z0hAesC24Pj2ygyAELyInY/NjCPVA0x3aX2K57TGzr2GTzG6n5ExvxOyaFLCg@WSjZ2Q0FW0GRV9WyOAimZBkU3EV4FZmxlJ0Lu5aapq@/NWUt1cYaPac9mAW1YpsnujNXvvQ652YnMHD0gMoaQcUhBXYxZrnQMtlZb0k8fjGZFqHsuyBh0fr1IQiGFHHebJTiE3w6OnoAjNzIM08IDoRw2McA0zTaYRKwFUNu36YdAG170LLw0MjAq0DNZSAlXjdlQNMLGbxDbhFN5RAQYkZQlgDAgVVfW8QOfhAU8@EHXagYkU4WIV@B1jnsgh8eSheSH4aPqBvN9AjPGXmTtRAddjo0rhphzSKy5Ocs2DqQnmnW18CzAClckpK1FJ8BtBk@zTPUcfirwRm1c5SXVMh1TFmCGMKiBixUVNCR5eCx03NfzcPVJHd04M74YQSkeiD609NTkZ6POvYs0fTxS3K@6@i2NOpbIA67UmAOR@G3ti1DGkV4ZyaBfShSHA1GWxMUamvl21P25rieXwvX4aaSPT@JneMJfiitPzxB3QoS3PMpQd2z6McUjVS4LpjRn9rKnkX0V0nSwwaTF4iEEEQzyU6zRhaQZTvGcbZ32q3@X@19/X7aSLLo39FTdHAyIFt8ObaTwcaz2OCEXcfkAE4mFzOsDAIzA4hB2IbJ@PzOQ9z3uK9yXuM@xb310S21hLCdZD7O7m/OnomF1F1dXV3dXVVdVS0/3NCEBOAwio56iVmLZ@rH2FNPw2nfL@HOcR31P12OfiLHAoCU4NOCoGnuoSq5VD/l7@kQHfgnzq0ozWb2MkXfTSyNDJxaktgjlrDt0xd4hG1GfOIUusNFa9kOVV/41WFT812LYCFP4c51L1DOp4zfF/x9Ad8X/H0RNKqabS3aLJLhqzvsDnI9RiKokghmqcrcce7h4AtBBjlc5BkEllyG3qG/crdItRW9@ReMY1ExBvDEFAjupLKtHy5aF@2J59xutreyA2D2BBECRhxAt9pE09ue/4zUH92Mpq4XegXbB4k3Em981b2S3MC8gn30B4gYg@k1xHyxg7F0eWKBQHYYIKAcBh9RNCjNU0Nz30/gTR@BcVqJgMaMWEsi0ybpS36S70BcYtIzYXVAbQ0Qvve7BGjCF6FmDt8bqlaHDzMXyqiyabrqEJbIpUi2k0DJyFThtWafBknDKp1WaALZUVwtRruivsNQtCKftG7eyfHX0X/62ej3YV7EY08MyxvGvqFPFYw6ABFCTheiqjgsauMKGGQ37ZEzg52rwvKp3K2hmc2sUjO4HeyCdzucd69S2uB3TR4fSmWRmCQKPissi0Xo4rLI05LnhSIpE9yv5slqS8UIsj4vIAAjF1vNkdUWerVFscgLh1isqXarIbkgJBdchUsv1iDZltVAe6qq7QWHpw3SKYZDJABenrdREIOmCeHZNw66cvx4PZ6iVqXaDNYc4gLJQyhiI59127GttzSktUUrAgAZcQVAj68ULxjRBS@f9n/5axSTUq1R/EuyAa8VwGC0BO8brAP5TEY6MAj8iS3aB2DuJrZaRiJPxwT4vxz/l7DUS/VffvVlLlwyH36ZsyL/@11etpGy2gTVpI98bgcXZCOwVOgmi7cuaIOBHUJzmNBe4UFR@B0sABMqxhrcGKGkSHG717xA9gWe4swe@JGkqGDlhCVK6mO80FiJc4/yjlMjgnLO3YKegblR9rWrD5SVIdgYhTipnlbEJkW@9ElwVkJzYpZgKYXReDqc3IcAneyR5I2TiKwWz70C/Ac4WAokkInsFymijfkgbkSRy@t@i9JiyYlAfCpSeR0bRLAPyvEEj9atxHNPJKxvoKKJjFupnZhG@A4BeUQSqg/IedNJCmpZiXQmQVXhHSYUQ0hhEDya@F4hDCijbKoUMVQo8La8DN0S5CygK5OBQ4qZnc2/yu19a1DvJtbcGre@bVub3WJCwBJkT8be9ey299PAvbrpi5GY/ni56C5/@VmI3R2BCUa3v@GIzPxeMUvxYxSpK77N0e0PEsHvKOYUs7dnlDk7KejeBw5heCroDgpBfgoFlAkjXCo2x4oL0agwL45be@3iBBbhcWvS3kezxnyrON/Kb6XwxTd5E5MmYc1UtzVvA13utFm0aby2QavBCzxF6dKjg0/Y04yQuWAOO6SHJ7B0cIG3Oo2GIOgTM92SQirDBUFZAYYNIOq3ahvVPmr2VN7CJ6neQ6WMqCHk2yEKJf4HD@8A9GiHxePVOV5mACDxqAskDLpLAHbZF9ustDsCe4SlYNce6EjgiKM5Bqe/f0NBxpC3NRjcVeoLGsfwAmaBiiue@MNOXTCM/7gedn86fi22c7mX@dyLvEYyvHUXEcxlXuwE2xUQSX3YRhef3fyOYRy70yX77sFmjrB20gjQEqeoHL8Hvcy5cSYTxyiNRuzk5@GlGs7sxullDKPu9Mh/9PKaKIJq3DWSC7Ra93rW5ZsYLocTe7ZEvsBrYujuBpj8@BedE8eg6vTlNYOWgVYQUMjGwznbStybId544lt@@u5o5N4iwbpodGF6YKWxA3ucsWmKMEpILIUL6fvja2@OUxqtxgjQvsRLcbs@GSaw@XVhZMiEYYwAFBnutMYmvQgm0F53ZKOqlYlDABrSKKAQgK71rrvOvTgYhMRn4iBkx1TMhq1GJuvODJfmythG1RbkuoDANCpUTcMdBrj5ptoQjdpJ80OpXhHw/K5ee18tV8ri6KNovqmI49q7j@SZK97UTsuVekNgaOtx7axZrx6dN2vwIlFqQM0EfTBKZx9F5ft39UqjIWp1UX377rQK0AB8vXTWrFYalqieHZ@el6tnry0BEMRZrSlOq2@rTSjWrFnUqqpmBPVE7US8rdSP38DP0lH1tNr8SC2eVJtn2NgJtFYS70r1ZvX4/LRUF@/O6@9qjYrAjhnlauP4tFR9WylnoH1oU1TeV86aovGmdHoa6Wjtw1mljsiHenlUASxLR7A9YkvUz3K1XjluYoeCp2MgHiB4aonGu8pxFR8q31egO6X6R0sCbVT@4xwKwUdRLr0tvYbOGakHqALjcnxer@BJFFKicX7UaFab582KeF2rlYnWjUr9ffW40tgXxmmtQQQ7b1QsaKNZoqYBBlALvsPz0XmjSnSrnjUr9fr5u2a1dmbCIH@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@dOf0xFTZsQUNDCTVFJnipEKW@4eqtXBvJyoZCkKh5kFHme1v6vvoBldzc9s5@5P0b/z3PLXQYRN9S2PBaVK9Nf960uQBMMLJsAkmG0t6YzWp1QCwjgdIvfAsFr7AQX/2Fe/WVQ/s6kAQE2Wt7pLeJu/FsuNCxh3X4db309uj85ASWTsR259Xuy719wz/E/N7ivx@xHfLupDPcKezjIKfRJ22WHIPgQzNFc8UP2J8YOJvFghjRoQaNXqLVzL9fi4UEToZBstQBdtfDjBATNIMknAndCUbmzKeG4tfYmSkZIBXqqom9GdsLEvFtkJWIB@Sh6WhJo7bAfxC2P/3VFPc7JBlIshj5uwLnGk943UtgJTpp67vXEz4GwSKZhOJjPhT3aYAXhol8QR4j0i/J29oogmCLA43zlYadagIST6NYCKmHkmc3NPGOrLZSuaSzWHjzveQ3ePwo3QXIecD25qV5A8h44tdEHThQdGWnWxJyGyPs8IhatXQg0IJgSqRo7klV1TezarOBUMHgV7ROhQHv@1bZaJOoCCf/lgR9mzkVTaEIZ19yrPwNnBvXHQllX1lj5W9l4xMMyzcZM9Vu/TYMVeSjbxVU5AyR6avoQfD/RJrEwD8AjROgB9TSXCoeRUmCyrQC9ZWIMrxVRgzNchJQU3/1MQBzpw/Mld8xaRlakCsBkkCOzlK9@EhOJP1UDAGQyU30LNDmb8916Fpz2JlBdfpbwpTV0QYz6Y6nKSH3CrVVrMBN77UtErssZbfBH6YwyTArtAZPoar4GytulzTrQWWKqPLiuZdgcKaypmY38TwjmPDEpUiRvJrsAWfl5CxT64A8uNI2nJ5//gRi6d1ai@Cm0ByOQmu/tKopQgHoQ8RntZ8UauiK7sj1nIj/Cl9P0SSfAvTct@StjtIBAD0N0MUJ4TzvCXlhojO/xQ1ixNDJ8SGAJlLPyfcCG@FjiUBwUMutmQHS0rZ662O/IOxvNezPJxxfQj8LQpXIsI@JxHCCN14Cz9AN4OKtvQSUR4/rNrNYdrPhWuLWoSgeNkvI@hh52XXdGYiONvYbcLSGSzMjPkijgzPxrmfSGwT2s@FMWiSU0A/NoNjE2jttMxy3Qah5Q5Ab5mhzQf6gLo0deyIdRIaL9J5IAfMqHj1EFia3lsVWXqQOgi8HQBNy8iIiHog9zLRGpZig0gHLIQoOPV@5gFnicjsHIhdMv1t39hPu/SgCTXpOz/fz0kDCCzVI1Ql5zHTn3PWp65FFA4YCLSA@JfJsSLu0uz/douQNe/RLyU4goOOrROBrhJ5g1JPPb8dnUgkVGwoYV7YOzLeXhsFEKm1LRyvf9Sq/vUuoxClcd2uVMfK9CpvEReJi4i8pBXkt7XMlOuITr5v@00d84msJneJzD2cPvEH7uRRBEWGUWdFmu7rOEX54XvFh6Mx6uk0UJJmePUXzG6k@7oR4UZkOpRNF1557zhI0gG52uMgSjE7q7@7VpHPsjuzB0B3aoKdhaMWCVzx8XNIjDthg5t56FFTM2ZO0Qr1l8EzWcHmojb@lxw7@DA46vbkzTelHIPPZsoTRs6jF0DE@nrX6@xXx9zR64uzX2dkNKvl1CI/M9Nq7At10f23dF/m4ynxagADkAncYOZ2hY3IHfR6LqiV3mtKOO1SBy/sKaDheirSwtc93azH@FkhEB7whjBUyK0ceeidQM1uLcau3sHrk0TFz57BulR2MWfVS9NqyMbcnrCLf4SlEQeRf5bSqlDizt0CvDnxYrif39ss/GXtA4CvQz7@I45Y4RqAlri9nA6zJpExIny3AhdyZh7RG00oMq9hwALvQKAS0s4hCDX9erqMGnSqCUCSdFla4EmdkChQfzH2R6sCS01nS5e1JkTTJUQBFkBLelrOWYR2dWXX/Gr0dPOLmELsMLkzHEnJKQ3odqbpAJcwKGII5vdZRZg/Vh2fM9vZjRy1CwKIkYAgHLWFmKqEkF/TE5ouy53Ss5c5gMU5EqCdPJZPe3J0mH0m9tWtH7Dl3HK275joifYowWxE2y80ekba4xMflvhHFJ8I0YYrRKTbwEKqv9OyzeZSIi2IH51uxs3yADutoFpzJ@puKP949nvu4Kd5gWKnaaPwpRbijy9e@/77VgY531q8gEiarVx1aMTq4ZHSW/KiBipDJp9LjKUTcJ3GP0KMHlMN2e0A7fXzWEjV6AK8cyNSnkMsQ0hPd4O2xg@vStJ@BjqRMdT7lL1K@wLmwlnSUl09fossmfmCAKBU76cAOxRbcYLAifESxFv1UB90C87gSwdMh@@wqzyeJqE8winGQxh127211lul8e58hLXxIoFXwDfL3QJKvsFirsyAoK6SAKR5DCr9HK2vT1eN79bV9gXIAgWvTZ@8aj@BBmsLOmGILsIF/9E@dBcrAQVOyZmhGhSdCh5YGmAugpQxGDqurKP0NZ8zx8JCS0wgUCH6dwj9bsgY6R@/lfGpjlUVviUVMSW6ebSYmTKMqAUPxbyS/nIos6pLiCgAcxhjqF/MAAZ3ECHs8FBg5/XmI80KIyjGCisU8Tkt4ST5mgQ9JzHckqiyws6uVyMWV@FaHkY4FAoJFfJkAEZBZ4osEUGCji8VFK/Eyvj9BCRCIFe8zxWEo5KiEaeiPHBOQkunlzGBFaeWFlZMcTB93ds3QR5@/6eu3Oe1rLvoV6ONj2Erno19f5UJfQ81ub4erhmoCPUy91dBHIIWpI@yvCl/3fwa5BGoO5ErCPdCUjJCUIX2/MNkhaJmgt2V@9MQBmjgOlYyh4NFhXDpPqqJSvzocsBZycb/fnV0k6cgAPeG/urcqZkNhIiMvkhcTcrRn4y4rhCSxJnCrx26hpkveFGg4IY8T0G@VTuv2xfvmyYmuBIvLpXI0Gjuz3Vwuh0x8qYcSKL8tNCUN3Wy4dLZ/PRplp7d/n72/zNLaj2mzR55bUBq0A0MCk8LLuLMBx9kgDlAUS6eBwGP3xkFd/7rf1wNa8IQSBw@GjUuyr1hP0AY09J1e3jc5uP4k2GD/iR3E/v1T@LPv1mZBU0JRx1BQG6h3cZNQp2dAHnzRR98v/6SKgOHCrLyZYN8yi4efcAfBODEaLHIGNdEsJNk/8cYZjVxLfMC0ZE8TZFGJVDg50SvkuAieMCJR0MVoBBxmCedmOArOpzwsovM6glMbk4raUV72GGlQdwaVxTSVaP2QgG0FuryF3dxCb19LJAYJU7rePwIs8yGg/ajSY3ua6hKdooVhq5czOHgCjF7krVjdJ1TEJJuYpNnDpZGo8ehmfnSHkxR03SRZQEUG0PBST9YU94mbuFjk@0jDHMOQONHFgI@qcbf/dUvj1y2LN/N@/3GrIgVV8MB@1orIcWVftyDSGQDNQDn9gJ4YXfmPNEzrk0ggFAs4GPq0uu5ghQ5WMIzn3eLPt6lSqSSeTbe2RKl0BA@Y5OeoJMr44uhIlDGDCv7@pri9u7vPa27Z/AQvj9TLO3EEMPia5O7VrAw/4VsRA9xguyct8lm2@Mzaf9YpHhzue9lW6aidzQ7giW@WypbkD7xyKntEP1o/@IUymUz2WffTs2/u9vF3q9xOPrtsPZu2k4N95DIgQ@l67lbnaTtwH83MLo0N3gW0t@RHqvRsD9O5yqpCpUcY27OfYHUpiI2ul92Qbz2Ow6U1dqPraO@dCSZBARVehXBEVXkDQ@TH9hLN8TA6XQcd8GC/oVyu5AfK9flsRRnuJ65WwD9V2SAEpMx64wBoPOFYQie5YYwfSA8nnjNBC/gNybzcPcOw4e9w3pH8m/1BXv6weZESmzmxaYnNRIL@4EUQmxfms@wQLxjhYv4VEcHRAroZCm9Igh7pDxS5GCG3YTyjAEiEpMKhqfDkenyJxmel/WH4pAxf9wbGE7oVk00kdMiEVTY@PZvcwbB8ghJ3CeMJhTPmMe8HCwodqcVQY9qJij@@KALZHjsCBC2PmSAFF5rEkz6ozGd@WfVGjrVBsZkEGMlaf31C8x5fwF70jGI68xFdCoNGKfiR3@LeuM/Bu4Q2fuH2AwToQIXVyRyFjSQ3knjWQXcM@L2kbgqK8dT7J5mPfR2WzhwrBs3/p9CYgD490Qn3bELv6ByTPjL9E0P/eEVrKsFlKdqeT2YMrcr4ejQfTkfyzItIhCPnt3bHMwlHlAAxHI6gLqzOMDIUYOaDW4fCkPVh4dDjpei52HWeCTLnKk4HM8MnRxoRsj@kYG7/GpnbZnaImCh2YB4gpHxXvr49HHlI8rlK3jqwZ5eYa4ESNYvhnM/NyJ6HOXUiGLt9H@kMQSaX82A@Q1c2pjN7MLYtsXHmNmf2sgrbFkg@827GhB5OknNCAiefbDquewph7pEcEqKI3xXyHMLo7dFSBpvz2OJo0GDQkKqpIBM04CQIsRNR0vk1NFYROgZc/RmDoKO8snj7p5FyiaWVFz2NJKSgC/APTbOVqWOoFvS540@chMGo@jNT8YKsdI0b7ZgOfmElx8zeqm2q6cjzQQHLJbaPu9PAmdihzWk6MgxOTPIsuy94X8T5TIk92BtJXlyUf5kP8gcgViBH/hBKcCMzXbh9ltmMJ6nUkwtPBsdv6PsICs8Z3xc/ayOryrNyCgcfU0K@88mQF8vIDjVk2gMTZkSVPP8BQn9kDwC/5a29RFa82Eh99zRrtn64mLQ3UxeTXy9@MQkTuSSrXTYtNuRhtlqx5FyBnTFrhX4qrzQPSIC5E8XFJFzgYkJuXXx6L0kAiGRTrR@y7V@zgNDFhmluZi82mCChIUNMsve3l0Xw2RU0N8JYZDeMJ@amqQY/9V3eFLC30l8cQ35h8l/AQimVZKYHPWfWB1AUA0SXFKBil321ndvZzu@AJjRwFumZc437bdq7vnQWIEp4qM7C1nPxS4gbQoS4W3j2PrxcQD@Hgwnmg6YR9WRCC7mEymlO7Rg@W0GdDPMElAcqp5AEGOJi@mVsPHxEhd8SwHKqLGW0YNdBjftSuH967hjbsT1c16LRIcyR6GXAPiJkQk0jZMl4aznUVNMlScFmGXF85cAgIxAY3uyGtltM3ElaCmtmJrmPQjRGzYwwr290jq5M0dAMfSaFqeRTkT/87uV//@/azxvzjcPt7IcZ/J1v/Lyx92qDH@EBfr1Qv242DjcOsNje3cYyCzowPL787/8D9Q//DnDwy/IA/jncVbD2lhuH6SJV@XXjcA8e8tvb0O7//a//gj48Y40NM9s861iCENtXFDm2J8S78F1UsZesliaDZSWPCwvCYA9D0M3hBzpGLbZf5chMtyG9Km7Q/WfYn/v@KHKLJ8esObkKsSVD@VOAZMQVithAmkEqF4q@0Hw3lNsGMm@Apvjn88yeBxrAP6U7h9@k77rx3EOXoWesFsEAprhF0Of54TD3XcJ37ygklE/JvhIhUbWTa@2rF/vADu9cZz7shr0k1HQdd@1b5zKDfJhxetegU028kfvjLHsDLDnOb7/K9tG4nyU/7uyUIKWny8wvIAjKbCSgGJLTqSVmMALuGP7CM@YoAYH@xD@TUtk5QMqeOl22YYUzPEGRRrNcqdctPh7G7mQCUTpF/4IAj3lIZFoNLfL8YgI1a/WCSGz5Bbkc6bwmYvOOnGNl0pE0e8NS9loQYKgPaB1U/cmUZgMKQqJaM4DARTJ2r9ex5beU8SShAs8t48mVM5oWE@QbBr3B69VAQpf0ZzFzLZT0EC0I6TQtdAhr7MxtUNGLCXqD@njQwhyvKeCzVtKNaXXxydqXZaVW3yue4JnWPU3fctO3MKIoJQTt@DwT5MKZCL0Yry1FNFXOnA4eqcU2DK15KgXWLEN/EAOPh6Xax7AE2R2KgASqBd2RXmX6sFmkCwOP3Docs8emRc4DZmwEwY@WKgGcVT3LoOyE7Wa4MVggztyJU0APZb4GDyMgiippy3BCAtDKZxU7LMFQH2pTh9FUhMKOWHJbmsB@SAIHxlIKIMHQ8XhTC3ywDd49fNASjpbQJ4GGl4SJLNUvkLJFBdVwFCipFjeOmhnbqVpd4Sfr6ctcQHTBG75I5PLbL3Z2916@@hZjxp/I3saDwUoZ1AKmVzbAIIk6BUo2vi8WE8kEv8KEXqtNIvQ4sHgAh25dtyZhxY9Pi/mcBJZLEKxbSkzF1aW5kkAGEGdOBncE0FFSs0Qq9V2hhR1rX/TMX@G/hKVqM8OhqdkeDX@xmfTaOLzjgAhKczR2xu4Mj8dxYbYpswvm1IcthL/oZR23X3fw8ir0dWW2h4ZOXReDEmbu9eBK544MW/tFEyYMEHw@WxZIg3rtcKQo6dQaViiLSoNDVYu@KCp4rdUeoFMubgko8zFwmGYwGdDL35aepjg7krAJYZ4HjFjFI0TNdVRnZ@LOiSsqZ@UoYjIT2tDz4WZ0z1YQ7mA/BPCV2glmPtK62wTqwpQYyF6rNcligz7pvnKBy2E54ApkeoyV7mJaL40qaq0muWGeuo8seeLFoZ/QLqgK44h4xcDM5x4mpYprVb1AgqiFUFqT/EXM8s9zdJIFOOmDjPMUeTlR0HxE3w49j3J5y8YSpvQopUIwkB6fSsQBRLtNLsEdyRVwROmxQmmseLT51ldymcSLUnmAfU3ViS057EtTAUWNc2YRnxbY/@rZsSXKFfjn5EPZQkH5qPQP7LefMGs9vnmJb74gqidqCIig0gxHPrfoM/UzhigBs@QsTl8SIIiLLxk2sB5J3kjBSvVE0p4ndSs0t9sBVyC72lIIV9ZROUkwawrZQJ5I5Z1MZzLXolToC2y8Wl1ptmRhNS3YxHX/xNZo8iRo1YfEpHwEiO0oiLQCEXD7k4Dh2QOdJG9b6i6Ksasn8TwdYllWqEBsP8kC2cM8u5Yy97HFtmSL7QKO4318QXx7L2/wBWZh5niAN55@GW@kH88c6X8L5qj8OdzxQnLHiwKuPcwdk@7MoRWJIjopqZ0bwzGXS9qDO73hYIj2ob72EzuRszQAtODRvWQ2xYPkc9i3NcuJSMV/2IruR@gktL27Z3xh53dk53cKuObSY9n5n9r59G/c@V3Z@d0C7jUxIy9FOxn@@tv1OBAJU@EXscOL4i4XM7@0p3uyp3sF3E1jhvkP72n6d@rpS9nTlwXMmMAHDpzC9X5uZkmk1DiuVgN3i4zKQJzCrIDxXGmi7oV3Y1uiP7r2rooorYsvxv@VxP8Vrkb0VEey2lqMsq/Ls3rKwfIsWfLteRhkxT3h/spQL72/csMK9BG5QfEiTYatmVRUQCC3@GNw2pQJ5Mdg9fU3n8fizGs75VbizLCaAs0aYd4MpjhLvlRYJWB9wow8R0vacbN@uvW/mAxj@ycZhQbI49De4h1DcifRVTAcK34tO6N1B2E3pM4RYhVJTkJ2LqO9fXZ5sn5Vo8QWkX0xXkngozZOl4wZqBzNA4hMRkCbjKyvtCp0zVXqBb@BvnOh@C7LHn8Rl34rufTbgqhLxWAdqWxp8JO8GOhp27u79@0BXCuDf3AC5iwof8@s@n/B4cKq@0epj9TpvHU8b0NLFmXoebq5jMAyIlymdA1lZgW8LmZyif4H7/3kU9uGlm0ZlBXPMI7flhtou7Avuz2nP7ga/vjTeOJOf5558@ub28Xyl3zCMFRy/pTJWQuV9400U6zma07MEpGkzWkta3MAAg3zSbaahA0hyXw@abYKhe22KXB@jjkfE58PBABIRJ14I7wjidws/OzhNJTswRCN7fXo6N@bY8w5kCw1sseXPVssCgL9r9N5S6A3mHzbBUICicgOk@rC6jk1TZPuhJFXTiR1yIWkpf/UuzobjKtsnxOJhEQJflbpQACNLX5R30LTIpNLW2wC8/GXYS9sKWGbjF9TptZDtUDy6fZO2ywAmT7QF2T4K3s05xPB1C@m7wnjzP1IAtw6j3mRw10kZ4YCFzSkD2gD9DtmSuYITrm4v9q6GvqutePDaAXg26HCIVppP7Zg6vuhOwAMpoJ75LqjUxxf1YIlqWGJV0FngkyIGNb8xh71/VFQ2YqH7FQZ4p1wHymHLFI7NDARQkhi9P2VLgimvsJmXWkp9uvjYQNgfEnuCiugdHyx0kqBFS6hNTSU04c2jWg9Hl5vzunEYzoRMGfLR4JyRAf8pr3fEN/X6jD6N/ZsiIYttrbloY2Mk4H5OSCH/7mcTLGJiuTk2t6FeeVDphlmriAX36d1KKdWX4LeK19iA7TuYAfwBl3VBdzNBpTd8GGkH4HyPdM5xKEMFtn7BLYjn70VU@f3pFCXTCLSUn6Mm3Zh7kbWnqGPcepVZLAVHXB67SG51Is2yyvB51c4zphzDPaAmc3uZBvifD6ERXwZ@DSTcEMOY7qURUmIGBjn5o9O4O6VJS7lD5lfR2KqLR5IG8rTf2UGicbXdE4Ba7E7xpZ4iWfuxBA@RBDgcAbkzbgVERvzf2bFtrm@u1AK@@mtCpaRLocGNb677rWOQO7Bfgbl1RPsIfo6vkKIYTvMAqsQ1FIrXYdxb5CfVjkbj6Q6Hcz90@lQqpVOB@WHTifJrbAwoQlB2r0Xpcve9Sw9s6/Gtj35e7breWm8fXs6N4wukPXgQCQrZ@Ukhlr5nzLTJYxDejMtZJ5@QSIHvjESiXCU6XGjIRrH9eq7pqBvBo1J1x2NHCkeSBmpNuvh/aDlYXeuxCaW8tSvsY1phQy6kFIce16DcOEe4uB2Ouj@3@mkPGfU10ZnI3iC/940356KJiUcbFYalA@xEVMUYWQwAJLUU0T84Gm5dtz8@K4CVByPDo0D9QcKHVK9g/lwPnIOD7L8l9958yWKAsupA1qgfJell1A3y5UPLt3eEv70hjeCPhUT6ui/MHNA3BreOPtQWactIdh33XmAYBbqI1AJLcsIqgp6ZRDkauWaKAi7h0c2IAgq5QEnlYeBIcP@UiRfJDNDj/T6lBluWd58IqXRJP/MYItJSyRvt5IxW394IBpvSkDL16e1o9IpZvx6V6ljGst1Y3E56ADToARL1zIkw185PM2dhIQK@jKXEmv0Y7jU9yQah999DL9b04165XUV8zmux5xJWhSfcoX8XfjTDfpUxX6hSyjo290qBmtQOTktvb4XC1TqVvY9@ooW5tiva5qqnb2uYQpKTJ25rkV3MgBNY9DBlmPIqz5j0x28qMN7FL1Vy0e18j00H4y4M9FGsTGcHo9q6rh2frZ@cZAuwvkwlA3DR/S8@e68aYRr@osVTBhapyyx0JYqbWpJn5SFuQ7@UalREZVTyniqfSJfl5EzVtAtsbR4UQEVlNZOxwPRxVKJClGMKUTjmula1djlyL4E/fl67uxjHGjh0910sT93p/IBpxrm@C1wrGvq013PGZj7F8anuwS3XUwAQycOP93xYnUxSfJVNPOURFSfzCt4@0ibRoQY5Uq9@r5SVvRoaJ9DJYFo1WP11adXdzjrYtycRjHKP2PJ7DMxI5Ra2YTpC1GeISQJBFOGwfAz@l0NZuhVm6ZJDm/3L13c/GAX7g2vvcJu7vm@TxeJyEpzDNLSF8dI0vUYOUF1GL3L/sTu/mado74g7Pq9HQKxFrTSyxEmroD/Rr97By8MOaKX7nzujtOU1loNL9cKfcfJFPrsA4DJtb42foypGu3Jl5B7hWSP4i01zSi180n1mDf5Bkj9pXq99qERWQ1X@NKezdzb8@nvw5oip8YNniQFaRUTSDcB69qwJy4MWsXoAru5Py@5llYsphAPpSx1YXA5ndlRlyBMzOw2XUQY/PqqyUxEK7u3k39JsuHu8bvSLEynOlb64wgV9O4eOoU4Zy2hNJr/4dx1Cm3/SxJNZ8HfiWrr1zxK2X7vmhcIMM3K982o0ILkp3updcrjiy8j@Or2q3ctEAiphTXsIfH10Y5X3@5Z4fvD0Wid4OureItVeVlKlGtqaurfYp28XK80aqfvK6JcfV1tivel0/NKRGye4dnQjcMH2bKpmTPACyGAfnRCpTWc1BSILoZWUBwcn2NRsBuehqPNqO8bNC3RdzgcZDhPelzW0C2qfr6fiTtxYltSTQR6eSEuxVMUNFRL/ppE6xV9Cde5xdtBixKuPBD6NWlGTe9QTLr1JNEww8ES5G2L163iPZarBuGRtKHxKIXoG1AWAefb5uoidPXY2ttxtSUpIkeFINFcmRHzfLhzHih2q53bXu0cEOyruicRRLtWBhpNAbz7Meu63h@OGLT5MGKgFf7RVMOolhDlzIguv3pCQS4I67hENtyiWRA@DZNBb/9wlhRJtRbGmZq0KysKLGsPriePmaL6OWpwkLp4ikq8tTKBzYem8LE7Wh2y/Nr@JWeDS9DpLfp/099FYs/irfsuuYg/vrfWnOrfB8i8Z7hjl8LIplA9K1feVc7wShrxj8rHD7V6GU3CjejWIC9@jwyh74lNJlRPtznrBlZVgYtRNoq5q@6JAjnmSozcLswKHAkyltFOvAiOGhk8B7/Ag7x5OXRSrA7iaZkgc0YyTI0VGMwmYnWdp2Nm7hCC21nlB8qked/k5ep4PcVK3eUj6@Zj6mJ@@se2vb2m/mPbfxFXnyyzbCyS9irEiP8s1wjR/nqpDxEaYNYN0P2TfGX4zN93AMW/3wiS9esrx08Znf6oQXz11yD6/3c5e2TlnbjKo0dW3o2pPH9sy3txlR/b8su1jOubOle51xJRi91nsLO0u/21Iv1JK5Kye963KMUPGtr9/hq2P3PYyPL6@QNHhsi/Ru7PHDm2BX/@0KE19K@R@zNHjuzRXyfBoSEyMohkII3ih6p7FLtwO@xegXZNAhD@eJ8IiRbNCAqBNdNJPYJM5mMbQ3XyyxTCL9X1vpTR2GkHrd7SbC2Ux7pkrEJ7Xa/D3hvvS6fiba1cPYnz4FghkOf8YVN6mxR9n2yBJRc/kvdNnNFs1mHT8qOpKmKBoJOgP@YY3h87ydAvqaWKt8k2LNuPcbVmf1m/nvkI32fpuXs7czH@3MMbllSI99ieaxzo21FKZbxU@bR2XoeBrTc@Y6L33N9nYN3pWjqyifNLuP@GHfTVGhjlJH9x5Ukd7ZkshZjB561kvIO2ZuqkWJr@yLUD1OgtJrnn1yum33Ab6a9pI/24Nja/po3Nx7WR/Zo2stm4RtYsS@XK0flrkRWNN7UP8WXoi3eFF0Th7U7dmeNM1i1h4TUM6vw@vB5rOf/TrICRHcIfDX92RCo9aL@Xy9FPIJ3491joi5A2ODx8PDrDiUqh/KjhoQvQ/sDx@Zz9Im6MmCp8TPGb0nONLf6sdpYmA3zIEM932PuerbpJ3vMwSaC0ynvu9ayrn6dQalocI/4SZKZNrURO3buD4W1KYQdaDvHBOC@V74FCX4XKJMp3g8TzLTumbsGAxzYS@OF@TSO@l@tKO6GFSYknxJ0Xk/jNJL7vsYtl4O3cWnEAbreSiFGyrRiSCBELZkMHlE6nscqnJDNqsvDpDmRCAgWPd@vxiPEAjsU11ut5peR6X@ZVvg@aN9cSdGWcY@FFQk584Kuu0@aa@DF/IsgczSH2kOdIdHmEfpFE4d4jt0UolXO4tkhaeiTPWnLycVoga1piAUsQ/hu34D/aZTx2IjxugOMdw7VryugyYWPtPKLlfqQOVzdi5lIsjHC1OIkNT36B4PHUXrM5any9EoxIHCG1AD5jXzlOvI/zqWocWz9w6h9ZH/pKsQgmNp6e@1M7mbxbszbwHKP6/uUJSBULiG7GxSnquB2uQ42QIG3Hk3QBPXN9SSykxSulzLXTd0pZ5wLo6@eW3ImnSJUzd@J8AQn574NEjOHA8AT2/U3sFRuJppTx0TaJFWkSKyiAyD/jpuyEhOrX8nSYXdehwzpiSdQrpbJoNOvi5PzsWFTPGk18UTuhD6fVs0rMqc4yflj07U8RvKWo3Q5SPz565Q0D4g3xX2kVJm1eEVyOvfR0I2b3x/4BLn9gjhHtQ9FacZRF8TKesGqECg/TIL5iC2C3A0V82L4X0JBzYvwbcEE8Ne7niwe1AU0jmLjCu8akXriZOAvQQbyk@dg1qlXY4WUJ9@rfaKfUBITYnXK92BGzGMVJy2vseepKjM8YOCYh3QcfI1tINVPdkmGsnXdUIL/G7he4OckFIerhFBqeiP5WOoJVt3TcrJTF20rzTa3c8D9FnHkxTjcapbsa@qaF4JqR4PzkpTO4nkRjTCn0bdJ7JGSOnY0Na81Qrqb4kNdMd@QCjVYwotvfk2uj9Y5Lp6elo9OKJE00YG/hdKUeizl/O1N7fhXtAauxKuLWLwa7/SwZyf7yKhlFT4cQ6RYNRuRdSLeW9SJFkNCm8VDkOceLA9J@vLZsKkiMo5XLMB2C1DamgZlFDQO5QKS7Ip3XA9KfalHHdJ2OTJvOry1MjzRxbmmq2X5SWuN/QiD3I8MrczK6MhcXXJmj2Ep26qeQ6P0gxjJxuJPblfHgD8WFM4llqqNwkL@YuqPlYOTCMzwAxbM95yY7uR6NDNzye8N@PzwI@vPhN9t4I6bTvXIFYPP/AQ)

Python 2.1.0 is separated from Python 2.0.0 with `repr("\n")=="'\\n'"` (note: `repr("\n")[-2]=='n'` breaks Perl), see [2.1 whatsnew](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/whatsnew/2.1.rst#other-changes-and-fixes):

> Applying `repr` to strings previously used octal escapes for non-printable characters; for example, a newline was `'\012'`.

Answer (score 0):

## 447. Python 1.3.0, 18900 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 1.4.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265557).

Answer (score 0):

## 448. Python 1.2.0, 18900 bytes

This answer is the same as the previous one. See [Python 1.4.0 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265557).

Answer (score 0):

## 449. Python 1.1.0, 18900 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7L1rcyPJdSD6UTHl/RHJArsBEKg33iBAstnsaY76JZI9Mx4AjS4UCkANC1XoqgIJNMmOGa1DV2PJXluWbFl@jCyv98pX3ljfjd3rcay8G2FvxH7ZcOwn/wDKdtwbtkP6B7rnZFYVABJg98jrDceNW0BV5fNk5smTJ8/JV3V0f/DTnybwIk9ce9q33YAEph@QrmedmJ5I7kzJtm75eVXjOAy14/XHQ9MJ/AqXIAohtu70x3rfJD3LDkwvS3zTJB3Tdk/BXyVkc@yMfbNbB5tGiGOekn3HsLoAgQTuselYL00P/HKE3DXt8@F5QAx3ONSdrk9GnuUE1DdPyBMdLL2xcUz0jh94uhFYrgNehYUkigu2EiEPXc83AZJrmL7vIqzyQhBFJm/rkN7INidXICsKec8yvS6huRh5JsuLopJ3j@7du@qqkS8KrkPuYQ6veOXIzjhw94Or8PNkp286OlHFsqhe9SwAngLTLskl@apXEarKDCzjajolstPrWY5JHkJZr3qWieH7gm941ijgoCrJPcuDatbD6iSG7kC1YaVuEHM4CqZEYISg23ZcyT7RfTL2x7pNwznjYcf0ooB@oHuB5fTJqRUMSDCw/DgeDe2PdMMUuqZtDa3A7BLbgkhuL4QCoJ0uOTanp64HdR/CdB17ChFNw@pZGCXKBwDEKxUMTAZnqE@BcJwAqIToxIds2GYELc0lIPxdszPuE3ccjMYBgbx1LV/v2AC0MyVds6eP7SBLOuAHVULdTwemE1I1gBMBxJHLcvXhmGbNnBG/3u0SGQga8nFsEguwRrNVIZoG7sT1AGsQKspRCIwSOCujOYEahjrruRWSl2Xw34tdMLe67bthZhazhp4ONFpaZwj3ief2PX0I2OiaFKfv7j8hvuF6YIMbw7KGdRMYQw/I5iZJ7j26myT1uFpEr8PFVVQjZ1AFiciTnOj2GChkviZcqB8vjs1hlSXXkhWSBLSoMsnlSA7ab4moeUCSIpfBAIxA1RS4C0QtkZwC7S1PNAisqdC4C@ADDYLkZHAsJ7OYfs/T@5ZtMuh9hF7E5gPRVHjKOaJBy9AKGgvdd@0eC2rQjBSJViKFIinmSRGeZVJWISeYbA4aTR7uAtwAsQzZBECqBpmWVQZs1i6AjpEWd0lPH1r2NEyBJmGQvEKKABXKowB0tQRQ4K1peGtwlxDa4jUPOxhAbQz0EwAv2NYxsjMz5mhYxRK8pI0NibJO5M0seX@AyQNqAan5EilC8gXASA6yAJhXS5A8eGp5yAKE0PIFKJgGd4EVzh@Yth2CGvgIipagKMMNpSkCfkpQY1ATqoyILsINduCoKrBOFfikCqxPBXalqmDWMFkIh1VYgOov5FgyA90/hoRYOmqXVgp0BwBGwVpANqkg4gAC1CQB9GuYUZLTkHgg81AmyEuxQIAwSgop5UipSADHZZlAnSmQL6QsBTi0AvlREBjQhgLEoUCeFKgBBYAqWp5wcxWgaOgPcTWIC@hSchAnB2aoTKWAN8QDilEgSQXSVNXyjHAhb2oeypvXKEWrBajxIvgB3lTIqwpkhmSslsAf45YAhyUk@GIyyxChIx6gprCJAH0CMqB6FAoXwoJZLYYErdujgd7B/oDF7PQwagGbTgHRCFFlLB68c4hNyArUsootBLKvAlVotIXBOxcnbysApIHgza5FmbqNHYsSY6iYpUT6oT4KZmhTCjRHo2kwiN1U5uYCs7WAYZp93ZjGntAys7HnzLWgoatK@fMMkJxDVx@4sTv27RmQ2JBTaVLmiWXP3ErUrWvq3Z7lD17N8pqjiXRMPXCs41kq@Xx2Dqn6nEcBPRacitp82MASoIvrD9A0K4taxDAjN66ghSwrCs1ex@yNnb4plEtz@aM@wdgLoDOapVlmzp7V70PHPoOjZGkxaec6c87THNqaBn1@5IjYxTQ9C7r828QYgMgSe5YZ/HJ5BkNTEcZU76AkIIAIBz1HGfu6njUhndsG7WlmGdQonoyBNYoCV1YGnqtcmsikVJijDYq5lyU5Ztl4tcQPXctJJUkyzV1w0D8xsXS@d4dO8D3s2bCvRtKFvtilksaMpaacqDdNA9IWBQPoqW0UoDqmoWOvjX2YSfvgCI4ViAQSAdnSdE9Q5qUd6UIyPu1sOx6KuCAZdU3PIxgW5GI/S7tlf9zxzRdjlL1m@epBP2@CONDTLTvOAO1b9IAKDfBO@pDedDHbPc8d0g5oiN2u7bqjFSIOdPKnCOi@e2rOsj6TAfTRyAZJC9xNJuhBZk51KqxTyX4@VZYhiITxoMIBIE0KJBTLMw2K@7DoEFsDWWYxixWi1m9rCOXOnAimQWMB8cTHOM7YtisgG5kG0epS1zyR0IWJaYviGeYhEtxA/ApBdHSQxjHnNBcxpNuqSEXCo6hmfXe4WDTW5@7HRR9YKEzZp/oUaq8H3a050YegMxAUzKHlkiFQDKtBrAlQLrBY@6TrOskghnLqgeALhY5LQoVrxElgDU1QnVyIgjWeo5nGHp/mrDMFUqbYyolUV2I5uYIokbuKKOaQm3NgjQVExO7YQKxh2pZDKQhEKB/1Ag9YJXPjAo80mzrcHsiAo1A9FNGAAQ8xa3Nahs9aeyitGxQiyrWm44Pi4ovEQuUNKL/v9oDYTi0oOzAsiDqDbVAkIApip4loiBxFORLQ8NgmFjFGIwLu0CkBed6TSyC2uh9a5CV42gNQO4yx503JZAQ1YQ0hVGC4vR5Q70tzNAAQZNglxtSA5gmVTKnHHzj6iOu6lM0Yo8XCzmzrJoRxUJ3ZffLzpG8C8kHU7aEyiYQ/K8ZoRAtCEaI7TAx2dMAXFsQYTSlyuMQsRs91RXTvuqZPScb1jmMGgIn5Zp82EGhtvRlLGqJYD7TqUHWkC/wnbGQIHxPklhYGkwpp4W3TgQZkAG1C04dKxJrdIT3Q0@eEW9RQdMMwR0FILS5lapYzpyk8voeaAnUVQmCiP@DWt8nmFdqBoDH9zEm5qDlh1kehAqMjxw0HAwQqfsTKKuMv9vRa8hDi5Erq/HMMs5CD5/yKPIxow0C1ibKKcYAMBXmkZQyQIwbIc6gkDm3OG18vPrjNJ@8NidCL08bcKMB8OFGKnTAfq2EIcNvXAYkjG2HVFxww6ILDa0Dr/nAJZDfOpN2ddxUlXQTW@DqgQ9dxl0AFZMZwMciiD60LSoyHyDt0OyZG2lz8hTpCtj0bn8LuDHrS0cj1oGUw1jOlYxC0yuaoK1TdU3GPkRbJncUOFjqOJHb7AfaFEGFk60AL2MSwpYLOpQO/AFbGVGvgfC5LcS7DtNVTWGH@TmkHwIgJelTHMVFt070pAwLFg04aEpoSy/OAGZ5gV8F6oqhLESmdQs@gd7vIXxEdtN1fTVxEit4dd6zJVf3dQEfxQ5870T3SQ9XdA9EDGlEq2fOT6Sp1pzHnvHjJHQUSjcqePASkgUSo8lTPF7GruAeM5nDqGCl@oYnxWcKPg16JT4MBIzJJjbwDCsPV3KESgUQzPIZ2TW1V0odOXBDgKaAbzQl6SCJ66B5IG9AIQdcsl7sdnZwD9/CIMNllCkmkmChiLk7LdLpxWiEiMC/z5RVZEr5nUIMw17dhCTA4LTntJBYQ@IaYoBF5cJCksIdFByrzMT8q3TDHsUPH@0iKCSRpchaLwNABpGhmLBBBLMMK2qHQcvt2JL6s1WpAbCBTAdvspuf12mgsVARODYFFKpOEiYiBexhg20ilobwY@ILlBoQnoNRanZwFAw9aHLVfcBAI0Mo5SMkRYsN6fmQdj7tXK9pBRwzEY6sD0ckyAr7KgQjAWkPtJqwmF7AKum8SsYrEi/Ep6GvES12xQvkwmGf6KATXwqzM1XAKcxDS6lIUsaih24ygd6eGHYoEzASNnXGjDmT/OBwCixlRNpQJokZ7raUyINgcGBzyZOfofi1si8xT6lhOZcHBdg3dps7rGJyP4j7Yv3Owc/Dz7SUwbKtTueogWblSAbva8UToO2MpJ6qV9XkYM8B32zfDxoiLYXgu9CaCO5kTlaYGdC6TCJ2PD754FSUgCSE6aApgxvuKSMPCgNDFdXR/cKUTJv1MBpKMo0RhibBPIpixAbOO/nqUnyfjly@x8q5mahS6Y87ssc4ARI7SvhPFE9HzigAWeXV6rEekcUEWtRyc35iZ5kNG@XkbZeermaEC9RzJvP343t5BjYINR9cEGkTyA5CldK8rAs3bY1DEl4UB9gcmg2TEWcZRqqZ5XYpgw1hA8KxuyQr4AAA1HtElgj2MiuYPIO@7V8tGXQUjpgBqpxCuypXz8pDxeTM6lw/s4gxUfJf1otRj1lnFTkt7rNh3sdsy8nmzmCvPd1vGLM3uPFA6nQD9QCQ3euB17AvoIs6kyFCsDrN/@OBaxn0qRIIqIEQ5820i0rR8m0PtRbBI0pd2QU9zbVN8j3I8nvBpSUpGMwqi4VMVdC783sQKUnKavZU0hIXUd3b21btR4HAwm45nUKUBNXLsmbweThEaPtCI49pu3yUbEIdJh1GCIDatLOZO33Wu1ZCOjljUBM4yAv/F4Rt9BH2N9ZKqjzTWvNLK5it1xz8FLq0UNEQSxRAFJdHw4of6iQ7ompX7cP@DPehElLwsx2aZXoCCuTgUXWgy5lypAxEgITHMz9ICxtOS11p75CHMzQtioUNGF0fcmXkvdaQcU5SWhl@apXfcaxj/0J1eIS1wYaQFhjmU7T968mD/0d7DnfebgZrPL9hzcrkAiIP0OiALiQOGN2ytG6xpYrEQXALahofNC7jAGBSUaJ5p7HvAuEUMIrIMrKAaNqGbescdOEk/fbUwp@grfOgYjIQeYuNjQcOIoGh3bVRGPDbhjf050s8gCEZ@RZKglQ/GHRGUVulDw7X1vkTjQcdg25KCqsv@Yxzd8JfFgMz4U5PFYENcIDpM6Tiibg9dUF7otDmyBpJi4OnYlW31B6AL49y66aXFmIJpaaQuaAigK0tx2SgDpjbAbfiO6olnpP2WopYYXSuympP4KNhC84ewaz0TVKcU9FaAivQVK2nebt4mU@DSCOkqkAQRN@ggh0@wL7AJCJJ07BT1/Ag5lFvgqCnyCoqjF2Mc0wUuJeXlXFEp5CVQy0BNA5lVwJE3YagHxkAIXAHgCW6PjhvMUWHPN3SnJ26EhiizIPfdgqJqjWfNptMCAb15m@YNZ6wb01ZDaaWr5HqUjTB8ugrUu1A8pN3IAWiXGoE06Zus4Gdd/To76@q0dXWJFAxHYZ8jjMjDHRCkXrrAr7vmfNvDCNK8p7SxEFbCwK@kJQNCNkbl8IGYkqBBQU8LpCdhvgQQelE8BMoBvjUXgcxGM2KBaRoMgH9oJLVLTenrEi46ayHXWMwKDg2LoymwPBoImbagYYYiD5rgiEHArCRBBUKJB/2TLAt0IOHIA5Y@gmpiA1q70BGAOufjUGSAXTDO2YzZ2DA2ydCKA547wgdEF17eJFxEoQHw5Q8@64VwYrFNJHd0pDjAwhXJLowokqfIAqAvn5KAjjR0TVTjcdnEU8dCRUTkqK8AXVdyvS0G3hrhIa3LH/zJ5ce/ffn1jy8//tblx796@ekfXX76b9eEV6hj1jczzaYgZhstwievZf7Wnnpr586tOyWaQ5AnIfP/9y/86t/@2i8t5n1Juj/66Gs/@ugX/@aXPv7rzz760Udf/vEPv/7jH371xz/85I3Sdf7bL7vGf/3YDZM8xaGR@QTD9CC5wQB60fsgtTU2bp2ekbW1NYi@trYFNbG2tUUyZAueAjzXoN/cAt8sPLdIA3zXSItctDjQYH2yZLRPpOPnoqkbgzZwS8NMaWkRuryz88k5GQwaExHa@TFvbPCtCzq7RPsCnHFhmd7FSjukK2cw7@9A981ss8yvSrohNRtys9U8SzW7mXTzQsoqLdCy2xY@/JSabiiiKIAb8paUJJ6VLqQ4bxMaEgKJxsCb5YxO2LGFPKhLM4K/Z02gJwJWCYQ0PyZPWQud3MGh1Q/M0WDqzQeIx6tAPsWx59n6EFxGg/xvnr@8ZPHnRaEFHTmSGFk4EAtx2AsljdGU8UWO5bQpLSxPinqsE6E3dANdelcEdUOc62iSa0lJEKAPoT4MEi32Q8s3QLXQHdMd@/NjdEuHDjF1cD0ajIF97w6sEWcaAxcofRtgkniWBJGMEz4CmzaKonUNEW5s1sgycIoBemO6dMeCyqetl45iKDTpE922uvFYdr4weiHGqVVpHCJjQlbfcT1TAERADI6uU6LL4Lh6NJu7T0eKrvHK0Jd2Ach3LTPIknu2q1OMug7Qwhw14lzILD7osxDlwOxytkOEHogWIqsBz@xKGxyd23S9AbBLKA1O2ahxHQ1DD8n1R10xmEBULoUd1Lwn04ZASDslXVVVC0a@V4n8kBYA2QOoGtTiHFAJIy9BAc90WLV7bBgl0mkfPb67x8YaaOeE3RGOO7WHbncMclioZxyYTj9L9oCKLMcdAit1ovgvj@0D1w2YVgyWVSMZTMm0hmNbp2MkV4cxboxnuB3XpkMnN0WdhR97vm7rbNAm8t159yHIxk@PDmtiZS6QpJ8Mb0wbx@2WJ8vwuT8/U0dnKaPpFJ8RJr@e57GbixZaInMJPUroMcSllCArhlo0tcaOYcAzRb7AsCvVjTicQsMxGWmW0JmiUveToNdbcNao87GAvMSeOeeoM1teuaAOeZ1ZoDwLhGstF8LMAyrQMPGSy5XhijQcW84BxDrzKFEPnS7AFHDofsG3TH1nKzBR@gk5WDxhPzDtaALuwBy6OMkEvaSNsxkg2qMgy9ZImtBXjHAugbJpnKGCLkGHiFcFLWhiI4GF5hJrtNl0LEfCiSJuXSLhCHGVNhzQutnMns9YqAuaMR182KyzGWHUPDym9Ehs7Hq9DSA269VowdqqYJhSMhkHo1Bp3iAGLSadBL9W1HhJg0@HpDkapcr5EgjdE1UWmpPiXus8KfkUDT3CN5uTW7L6PsgkuBpx/bbUN6t0PdAKfFUjnyRl2GFfztFQbHjXGAB3IZnJIiqhfsZOz7W7AptLAlojTAvBCgon9ONVkuFiWNPyogWSdIUqi4pcdW5t5TW4V6q0fj3A3GrMGBCKD@T8OHtyThrHWXIi@iPbCkBEQnliEK4qcq6u26TzWbrn6VOfC9eD1MjOwdvvNuQWg8ANdZwfKrFanETLf0Fr89wxLtgGE65qCayA9vp01t7C8oKQAxHoVAJkH2CwBKokTigsEZV8zPNZWXom6HMpk4pL02GWmOkLsWfrQWA6jObYJN1qdLPZlDCZGk1@KxyarxCZzl9YPcgl@EEWq@Tw6O7ewYGIAl0quYfzHBVojiA6gjCyqtARJucLXyG3uklyC@OkUbnloKmBut4O4wNRV4HoxybO5iDb6ZteChzTOEVhgDOdFaIRmTQWIgjXJhkBxVEMLAXK9hYDVlma/6fOseOexjVeAYrPUEwCulO3KyhlpsWxY70QfeheqKAJQUJ9CnqJ2nqKcrJ1JR0uPhviBCsI1VRAhBI0GgR0Jn4dAvOk1aqymXIIC37ghtjleVoVdJV4TYmqvgbOIMhQCGH02ivyrCEL5VZmfRkouhArXODNyj8HFyEsgvbNpcmup2h7v9aQWR7YjBnj3k99uvxxcZtDhawzA89GZmnwaHERZTp0LdLimqLFFUvQyJCV0AELLEjEEhLh8vuQZqk/5fyg9WI06pBKk7MY6SqinJyfUxySdZVQHIJJIawyLiKtGBjTAxdK8yBcej8vE9DWGi63wDbb5PhKrM2Lsijz6MTkdOnkijAqnFDfSDNnwqDlHLt0OiQ2tWVRyaMAGMceHtvXY@JKTfpYCEonUxeypYrF@Wz5w06PPpbEodMB4UQzdaADzaHMC8KiLh3QFx1zvh79yuKKyJnp92zxJu1bwUyEF68JKZRLNHCv07FWBYXS46qp6L0UCwdIwaqYE5VZEa@uvyELiA1Xk4bv//5RFxB8Hf0D6AJw5C02tKFTxqoQlmF2ISpa6GN5zbEB4rFt6RQB1PQ6kIbuQZF0OzYsB00noQUBOvYhDqmHNQvEhw8QJVcmo4Y5ZzNi0Xt5IssmlRxghsaqsFfWI7Gk6PQHKGpdigQm3lgmjUSZEqsEc8KmIOYUZWRQr89UtGiIUKJl9T4YB2P2BGn2tZVojfBejoKFkHJe7yimxNZv31Dlnn487rrC6LgfS6CFJWFnpafjQwJ09OF0aBuNy4vPCsjWQ0fvVcFmnZZ0Sl@vowrfGfsjoUO16i6z0YYwvCEFz2bPVUGscP9bbFiNNcumjzekxBA6EEq4GkDCFZfCHNKsK2i29c4UpYvB56eyeGYdOE7NyGRkbcXU6mi0Oj5qkjR@ubw89kQ0GD6W6fwSW9UZqlS0wOE6z9fUKvRH1lC3BbU7Z1zJtJdNzF8LGs/p0Ti4BYHuQ7iRyLHjMca27s1MN5D4tWHkawPSUedoGS508COiFEVFnTHHaBHYDCQun6WPuYl@axnCou0TQmxa3thdI8DFkSuo5w1YF1uUiEs/58hBdFfhxHBP8V7l7Q9AvWTP5X3Xy6W5egM2JNiGrUPPvJLxLwzr4bDha0jy1PJN@liO2OOlGQ0Me6n7IrFHA3bzA3CvI2Dfsl2fHNLnTQjqe4AF9lxOuvO4tHRHoIPX8@YbuE00mz@rUN3uu3ah1Jd0eKys9bHXQw4fvt@Ul8W8SFFew4siQcd1lPC9koMfS97x6yqIbtrzcCXnnPGGznQZQwpnK1aXDoR73KmwvGT35BKNKUpsUG9Fwrh@5VSfRu@foZNYhdqokxhNqYAMchxGKJfAEHhMaP5ZUsvdnFr3zZjSNbDF1xVirnKPbRO6Jfq8VqVElZXPGUOR5TdnUT17bI7NparD486HZthhvHnicpjd9XAsHYfvcctFHOplqMy9Ue6w50XbjUxDx@m61wsni8xrBPL0CNXcJ2B4gobrMfrOeLRQewt6lXPAUDMYRU3U7S7kAn0@L18pvUbGWZCsfZPeN@o6TDfDpU21vCzLoegxN/exYLlJB9LiuB9a7LmQMHWZpTwLi/Nd3pxxeRoULfOL51ayFHWV6k0Dl8uSYzlmMMXnG3LHjuvan6emgEnihlcX9EyBLhK9qcauiS/h9gcyG1zwcUii01s1rMB6j1ArBPyguntTpc9PzrxRbQo4/TjEqaFF66qRlaeOrQ87XZ2kOqdu@jpQ3IuJozNslah90yANHZ5QxJJYnNVO1@2Yts5ek0LupnhlUVvStsNZT5wlZXOjs5nsxBXeMZpCWa0uqAcDc2hS6w3itd7FUx3C18pAExfvVd4T0zSkyZ5prAowsqBZO/hcmIydk10C1wHFJsAFZqgg2LiEMXRdjayHume5D3YevT0/qx4G2B/qffNepB3MDQngChmmOM2MywcHKuQONiUDooVgQ8HSOTanfvReGvHh1ICKGg9XNjoDhwXfoJWtWvR4vQtzBu7AGZgDttI4tq2iUiCkgAIOqcfpD3CR02i0sPh5Hg@2a9vzeEAWwxiO6/aWprGHmyBx787S@Gxndfh67TCVHrDGh4aVZDowx8DHfTdwR6ZAbauC2jikwZ6reE40R/uzjpXcqNECKqL3zwr/tbpVX3eD0Yi@2iN77NMHjSrQPaqvkyd6bFEFXf7men3xpTvsiKGjGK64oNO4y9t0xwqMAW4SZhRp9t2OMbBel@nwYAIpGtxg1jfS3RAzFhHuojMo9IBebyoivdTm/Q/xtb@q0sNxEtYZxIYb@vdlY1F0G64w0o8Nn437oYlUcOhzrnWxzboVut258mJsBTOgc6tw4oFMNtCOhlV5DxcPrJRE6Gr4GTsMFxWspFIqvKKgKpgyCAjKqmQX12XNNTFNY4@lvMFwjeNexJ5XYjJckEKHuKy5wUdwXyCdhZU0SyVrZzDu@9d5Gxtz7oK0go/VGjldkDo37grdgu6Er1UYVG0Jd6rBuw3ix9i8cWIgf@PMAA2n2ILuWvBqwwtqZbxyeMi2Rj57EqGnrgoWLrABNfPqrBbDzXS5nhhWTNfssXF8NL1OJgP9GoTXPvTngoETvTgMjHyaddqMJzluH/i1YJNZ4CjsKl1p6QKY5dUfd2/C@4/Mvo6rYR9YAa4bXEIVtH0sWzjzWthfGuu@9aUxlGwVseHmezZn5s0vm0TbEngP9b5l3F@oiDiTIYLDRYfstUD@6HS9Lk4Hlo8LbmLDDWMuSHKMiJHq2iBCLwl5dfA5Pndg1oDYXraloZcNELujKW75mVLTTWPDVkAHEMP3Ki1q1fKmGzNxOh6Oxn74Wp4HuqRnfoB1yNiZf2oBcOEFcE0y0O1g@SDs3GgiCFJhfzczLk@yQj6wbLdPPijJBOSugFgo5y4hnDvQ8z7B9SKes4QSadpvOHeHOr/A5Db/BdStiSvTHSu4eQAjCHDtSPTGwrBOwT0FeeABPsXtzwtBOFqOkQdznVy8j/Q1XTRQ2KE79gwTjfHhEPMSeQjd3I2Wvlq4nR4Ptzid12wM14ZmBAZ7adMwXGccCN7YuZH7F27k/hU8IGiuuknqS3sPn6bna50uEH6dIBkdITUzrZzdvkJMlgOy1Gp@uRg6EvvvsqNtDug61dfE2cHzdwzKlu@6y1SQJ1PoKJYx8/HwrmngXNZr03jkPnQdF3qXETC@4YHJNmIvrDJYHhGjPcCtxoCH7muTOaRgV3QqTHrQR2YH6tGemd6kb2GA7@qBvqJrocNeVCWLTa@lCcvumN6HdDxrzrxKa1zM0H1zQtWA1YTB2poQGAaTXnGoaaEtLEwu@CPXddiTck8ZXsrDm7kEsHb6ePPZWxFXey@o3ktVqcWiPj5hSxfMLjspYFVZPbPj2ux5w4IYx2IT1bpnmb70ADeeU7dCjgggTfk38orijbxipsWAZHqi@3TmeLlWMAOpTD7HupSB7hkuTtqEhhuWjMztFn8NO44XkLPZ7A4gfgKcSTfG4dmOr8uWPewM6WOlAjBXmwcmJNPFlWqHUyfQJ9crkw2@hPvL55YZxbuyI7aEjbpAUk9Au0gvV@CuYM8a0QflvCtncOlKEcGxTOOljgNNLsXLbHh1wR/KJj2ixhXDrXPNhQ6ESjrdZry0xSyumwJBxDaFYOCBGi4FN43QRmdcLBnSHw9NnPdcnEhYKXK6/oAW1l0@xRszUc8UwuPWgGfER68xuU7YWSkxInj4P77zjgSdaruQi859ABb1@kllyPzYc8LXm1DaE9cPetbkMeQbF5evYhtYrDxEgRdrAWjaWFUIqD1nbLMBgf7cop9hl6pRAj08VxBsypYDUzCdE4GewjW5XiKX7RuSdvBQ1cDsCuEmdBwsFx5EW4jiYOF7yZzePA/EFYWKxBA7KeTCNYbLkHsacQCQn9xAGPn0LY38J/sPHh@JI19Z2g/tDHDR/TW5bGFXu1qS50aJPtS9uak5thaqa/mBdOdQEXYf7IsYYAW@2ei9AC@cXFp4rRyKjA7SlPSV2gv6msFyge/@0cMHmdmOO5LaHXju0EzPe@8eHmZxA8M7h0u952Pfg9bRcycro@/vKUp6CfmG2zJXccklKa2CdGSCFgnEeJ8divFaIcpwR2b3aDoy34VOEjm1/4bJF1YW8pF@YvWxFZLySkTRhkrKYiGXnlv3C0qy6cXvVfV5bI2QWxr0JbHXyhUSKCFokqctlxJumpy@Kq0QOZwc/3yRFPk6tc4f5Srp/j82Y4qirMLzod6DeiX5lZW1GGDZFKftnrzBbKgZKiNC7CQEQFWC9drFykVhCKxbwgeOmIeOYOysXJlxE4DYubC0wZ@azlR3BJSWQpeRG0sZH5hzczXxYpETPOd56bRVvN6apAxqjNB85M157e7e2Y88Dph7aHv70VPyRPdB41kC0ZyDOJMsPhRwvAaP71o1cLHf9YBTs36iP1pO9xVyqHtd15lO5poKzuJiV0dPrIzjoI0GMm1rYi3j3QYbn3myfCVIlAZbIe9OF@S8@RMxwgiXX/lVRZFlet4JvhWZWa8QMEmhSZ/iYVnzXkf7Mekb2C@L4JBeqlU9MCe4YoCNUi5TTpfy78INvL2YXs0ub/Ir3eCXuyG9a37oiJsplBsA5m/wI3kx9n7g2qcDV9zVPfMGdNyU9fINWS/P8ZvwCGY6exWaVwutuBI8fC2ltyMz8HKjgduxcgsi8uLOyZXD7YHu0fUHfTdcPM/sy5M6HUcN@aH@0pxvwsczPmAOxrhkfMlEWgcEMdPpW@zENXLHDfao7QZtId4Yunyu2RrdHY@usBI8nP4Kd3oPlDL31Cd3cKvPTD5colzi2qLl7quEKRKPMOHhgvePdqJEHx9K6lyKs1y8/2TBGTfDBY8P59w8czJZpW0Jk1XKy1KfWaqPjnILyW7Wn528Zl8F9GzA6uL3yi6X8Z13Dq@3TtQUBsHQjnze0R0zgtN1A7o7Kh6Hm4xmg6PvDSgBRHxsyYIu6EUsC2D4UruNp5W026uo5Mh8nw4sQ19JAnOCYj0T8MNDgcxJbhCE3@ugUVY2APc45tqHo4HlTELLcOaOa91I6kM/KvEOObTdUxIpPHPNJ@yxIIp@Yjo3b2oSytrNHbI23@su4Imd@h@@VqHozore@47pecvCHBjSvcjyrppeEuKdwyjAMt9d28VB0q41Hi7zplEzmWVe3kLDvhrJWuaBh9YfD1zPWeYZVUylcsdcCXrtBr/hFLS1ZR6dXm@Z857vLnN@OLYDC4W0yPORO4bWE5HVnhdJb/XNerMpVsSZFc/g9Qdeet4FOMXQHfsg3ll2@mpQ4UMrWHC8gm/qhocAm47ouFfhvuOSL1qzfM4X4uVKLL1zb@azOE48xplCujtuZly1U2o01V5Lvi@tPrUsJzzHGl7xnZ2vtO@5DrOl5@d9otOVlkC7r9tWevVEqPqamVBkc8yfnGjLWhkw/HvzGH13Ookl5yc23asb2nZVKEDfMNLhNyJ8uvpS0eYGBdiSkRXL3mYs@0t7Q92YH3JcOGQhmjbyZ0x8TrPwDh/d2Tl678mD0P5FfdiJUojORVfvslVb8RqNK8Mo9OR46RCfgj/Qoe@iIygCbpu@MoP23s6DJxE7HoBIDqjEw93mBppivktSXc/Xh@VYgnwY7VO6C20PzTNOdH9qusI4LhTr75ap@St3D1w9HOrm0HNHOl2rjUdmcDj2eumVG1nV5crO4YNVbPWdqJiHbz9850v3ZtucHllDIosq/K@0DFER5atO6nUn7bpT7rpT/rpTQZSvyHwrpEGxdNPmZU0sX4etXMu7ej2j6vWMqtczqsYZnXOSrzstSXEJthR5idu1cMpcNujKVO16isr13CvXy6iIS4CHWWWb2UFymf9cgJ8Nj61ihz@wLfe@GH3TIZVyoMNIL35aa/78ADxUO7WOh8qu07MCIOz5OVkL9@eDBx/t@A9PJMCzJy1nbOKRAuzjOkFtHZKp1ZR8mWzhd6sqRJFpmvixvzI74i9KrEHWz8Ld9pWKckHWaoSv8CQ87yA@sZudOg2A8bxcKBQRjhWyHoDPerRXn9DPqJBzQseCBQOPJQWbKM2fWlINTzOAPK2fPdl/snd4tHP09LAhty7C0w6iUjgOpBadqXJL6/JQ@BBvoIOzM@jpKRs2JEe/nYFjyH5ULoKfjVosWm2haLNC8VsYZ/3McSSJHvggCReQP4FnqVFfFILBicGOSkwrKDzro8LOXqBHSEAdMdA8TRMqrULkZQmPdN@HYoX@V7@8Rn3xy30V/HYfJhweGw4yd991u2GKvklef0Up3tvZf/D0YI9EGZxRzanVDQa1cp6dKh8eKMfj8Q82PRklGUZJQl3Vasl7SUBMUkySCj2ig57ojofPJWN6wMM9wtgbJLVO4QMGk3GlSP/9I@kiKeLGkTSETUaZSkKyQPOUUPD4vSMgEnL3YP/dvQOC@d@7S50RRQiCHOEpAn/x/S77Jkp0alf01UJvGOqYUFu@a3UreGiHYZJETlHDk3@6BE@sY@daEHNCvy9CKY8OcM19xzBNT1Li5k8aiY7fmJ0QgjVHOcB8TPbtEnryRvzRlPjbTxxHTwYEej@lB1teOfMxTc9VY99oZKexxqAp6UXfX8AJYNCJqVxk@Rae@4H10HPH3pVGglvy6RGnItnBDzriZyN1@nkfyOzYCdgRceGxUQmgUDHmVVmyTjPLPgbEzwVMbq5BI@mYfcshvmOBGBxUyIdAwTj5WmHnwghCPXktSgS6Qk0CKr5zAZmSPsRD9okw2sOz/pqedPkrvyT1qwTMAZg/Cc0T@Q7YvhbaemD@OjM/k5BApeS1b8DEeZnPEJ4BG5aAZYTrWT/9KX7jlU@tK8px2zvJJPNyFR5KNU/y5NZ6UxDWG3Jte10HRAYvJk1oztJG7sS8O@h19/tSk@dBVs5J0sbZ2Vny3sYT61meFISupRZeTKYXWkF7MbnQlNKL45FSaIgvJi2@VMset5qNFnny5P1X7VdpfnJCh0hTQGC7j3klxycqZXK2VdASx2X8/huU8Ji8hOu4R/BPzS@7c2YdzZ0e0G2SJ4lmEz/Iyhd5YHvJFvwpp3gOF@MZjbpYF7dar16lG7oeTKbEsqyR3@3C7Q5ISlXThwSa2m1oRCyCRJr0TZEIV3446ZHJjtnvj/f0qTW@F2yLRbEkqnOMafPhB@@FV/W9p08JeUqePn15sIKNtTKZlCA0qHkSOT4A8TU7IZW2nk/gF9z@4rO1i@zZk/bmX3w8lMw1fD3G1ycXD9F8qORvra3dunMnl8uqqsrMTz548vM7Ozu5u9n8k0Z@KyfIa5t//mdra6q6qUprLd9XWsnG8fH7vCrnePEvvpdsP3nyJd@va//1o1d1BR9FeJyQIinjpREFjPgswa2QfJ686ZV4mVDgSkzpr52I3M/WiFLfKv6Pbz5@kQgSdVV6z4N3kHiRKJQSzAgGsGmR7SRRT2xisMJFYirVajUwFv/Hv4P49XcADvpMN@FRz0ewCtNEXajRKOeJegEMiqpCuv/PRx/N5RD4GbCSGrRIoRS5bQNDbDT4XFHlt1pwbdBrk8PjkgRZkqJwTjAITJcopdvKbbRYYIGXAy8c42om8BuWj7eJ@OwgA31CRny3vibd3RTgEkeSoqhNRbkN7Fe4tVGrCdCv0GarafnbeJRlmvaGfTdwiXn7vYUr8d7/lGspmOp7/zTXAdm1DNNzs1yisLb9/G69DiXX6tpGPUOvsLnRllcs8a67DVznaDD2LBc/i1l9gB94qfNySeWz2ez2QRuikMkEkSlMJmIbQRD20e0Eu8Q2YS7YsENHRpVw1ZEntEjszmJF1lk48jzZgNbSer46XGIPr7/8D3/57b/8Jv19m97/CU@dcrpWT9qAQCfQcOpwbVcqRr3O1z3@rIn2OlCbXClVSlL7opnaaNRbByDgvn2ezGtJcmhPs20Vr2a62aDx6zTZepg82uuJmXOdudTn3UIPFpg6wDvEFElE5ZwrV4w1Qq6E4xLRgimhcVJvCTjmWhMaSiHfElisxjZUDq8Wy3y7lRDWp5j3Vl3Nq4/Jdp1dZLDuExdzo6mFqCBhfuuzss18Zrb6vFOiHkWrz8J83nBhnspQMl8KZc96lNHttcpaqVKoqFK7vvqqzmLgRYOapvnET5wk4qtKQjqM8JmIKXPO7dl8TcTVQiICJgtxXxOOSzRqjZbZgjay8F@8aHVpBYWvhia1zZMq0IeqCWq/zcsKtLbtdsTOt@Bagx/9wxVb8blGXUJnGuT6tUYqyoaqSflbhT0V@@CrF/GERj1DeaTQqmdE5JWCeCUQB70KMTqdzkujAzKKrnd0Q1cCfaxP9KkedMadSScwxgZ@7Zg8QUGvHZbe09y8W3IjZIhCQssr64nbSOGaWsYPB4OWUippZVUrKlqxoBVltZTXSmWtmNOKRQCoFVWtXM6pqlYoaoWSVihohTJ@nBnCFCCMhhCKea2scYlXjTVywPjbhGSiq5l57fVUpBwNL2pw8RYEd5IAEWpsHGe5xD/BVVdUhWxANynDA2RDaiQq/UEJd3Vr7Gc5kgCx76z1aqPxaoPM15YQ5hleYnu7lREuLhpgrlbD/2Y9NlbpxUxQ1NZFJrP5rA7S0LN6IwMgn4UgRYFQoGK7Tlqb1CtOLUwu9N9stfrgmxn5fSQZgWbiBWQis9nYrLm79BZp6xRakMrmQs63tympbUOs@jp0C@lMZl0Q1hoAuhF2UBAYCTIsIkCCYCkQZc7OfsabbG4Ck7nYvKhfNDYvLjY34b9JnxfhG1zB@yKZc5MFd3uTWuI/fc2ui0XfKMzMv4V8qtmQ6k2pGfKqFthFqY4uotQEQx3eEK6hqaUW9o4oB4mtf55/MTt7xi6Y5ZYIueYSG2Qjgec1aYkNLvH88tP/A@/m5ac/QJmWwM@scIkzQriEtFEm1I2@yiDYPXTIQ3Y5YMY7sqILOtQfoqPDHg5qypL0XCQVgarLKaVUSIvY/bfdXhs3xIrkOQSFYHt9ExpRxHsJr5YKfDujTFWS2OQLRcpuf@7alUwm/8VztVxMMm0cd3Q@933/4VwuZ/mEwFVVVgTlvM4O3mUno//csutf/Nyqi0uclwniKEUYXrgEkFFCkkCL5BL1zSEuL8Svigj4ebiT2vvC0x1h1x2O9ICq6ziWB6JCbX@vVi7XUY0y15/QxrNxdwOeCvz31qAQpNmDoM1ezRiCiN7saXm1iVrr2zpo78DohM4L/D14iT9yZODv4AX@yNFL/B0E@CMPO/g7eoG/nQ7@job4u/MCfw9f4u9pH3/NL2iaUuXX9ZPupAv/ycv1yfoZxVVGKSsX6xOe4SyxVW9@AdDpJ6tkO/mFBh0VypdbDfRtgccXAm9a0Wvl6qimVoc1Iafmqi9rqqBWw49ouH7Wn/pZXBVqGlgTppHi1S2VT1cZpWi5cvoLbJym0q7ZdNCFpPCbJCnXT2fAkIJOLB0FfyWEoETLj75nmGIbiStqGodItHLe9QSdWD48wCGjlRXXS/7kGx9/nKzVkkKSnj2fAzcBP2gND3BolLOKmi1mc1mllFWyUA45qxSzipwtgV4pqVk1m88WssPsy6yWVeDfajTazxoq2F7CT4U7l33ZagB/zd8utlqNl61bSrmVyamQGchSLv0FQAMRTfZxq@oI8MUlamRdWVdkWzZkpaN0wGAR2SPyQB4oXYUqm7JJ5Kk8JfLQVbpgMuEng8mSe0TuE9mRHQgGvmAK2nKAph68@vDrASAPfhauquooskEgIRsVUvpZKaWNMWVy3iZvD1w/yI6aXIMkCf/cfP78OQ6MiwWrhV8ZaPDPnzeljZZaLhER257YbjxvJlt8k8czaNVyjnSm5lrzOQ8SlMyzNoouJOH7jWSrmpCaTYnVIKCe0tbFRbu99@huuy1hV94kZj2znYF@aHu7Bv1S@NpK1KtbzQrt6aLeLiFtbjXrmoDmQgY6LRXcyH0TSCcrZT7nNQMM7/oaRUDr@elzUNhSp6i2nZ7A6zQyvNeER5spdNRbOn2vOWelBrgwrCS9twTCggFy7XjTWDiDP@i//1R/65/X/@FTkk41WunU2cVmil5p/KXTZxdnF@Gznk6lQktqE37oAHaMcnZRRyMNdAamRirdSl9cMDd4ptKbDGA9TVKbdRp3Fg66vUScJE2WPVL/c94kLkwqvJrJ6nN@c9MzzptVykRzcpkk@OegPOmzqZFmcyIDc@hEZ2MLDlnXz@k4crpq4Ifn1jsNpfXn36Pnn2@laaB8rlpVNgizqDm1Ws1FtmKpWi1FlvVUqnz9qstbSgFUvFwOWGwVLFsRWBmsELdBXmVIjTTh2bp9myVSUs/PI5harpCRcUqqWo1SykOypq8btJ2D5ne2/5ieHQ6MIp8gyA/CQfWUTL89cKLbqeR6u1aZ3L6dCr8vu7WTvn1bLcvn54pcyjRKyIHlrKYVs0I532pUJiL0vwO369Mph1uFVpKkXS/1CL8FCkBTgkJuqXUKvwwcWM0VwZsAj0hhciTFY8eS5tPpTQ3D5HIQKgW9QB4Yvkx/RfpUsTcAVaiVbmBk2i@1252xZQfQEbXb6fQtRQM@r5UBA7FameSTVT5xBuJXqWj1yNp6m/E8voo@5H/llSDAacjZRYISGcnl0yngzGkQwS8S@POQibOeOJ9PV3OynDi74FlgpVxmodMkV0iVMuXwV1tLkzrIl@yHQrKWyW0UN7ZxtNCfrLiQz1fPzJpyUTszK/hRnIuqEX4cErddm7dva2Wo75KcIHfHePhDtsmFnUQNZA0UVeHR5JLJDLl1m8M96V6yUt2mRKeU8iSRrDJHIQmdDSmVM4qkbuSVEmKfs3p4mALIW5xCMbNG1jiVvvHBlRm@1tAxwSWuDBus/nNduEiXdEgfL9JHtZ5YxKYXsQnzp0/DiAO57Ap9YyuNSwcCIhczvti0hpbXWMNKkgdjw8IBxScPdnb3jrLqpkAS6r2d3ax6@PROQkFrfman3hraD/Z27j5@ChGePNjbOdx7e//dvadPwN0np7Mr7tOini3u4eZMS@yn5D3uQ@@lbpq6OTbN9ul4fPqCfGhZbQuq3B5D2dy@R3yzDUUa6bPiVeE2LF//8EPdG9GLXH73K5ff/YXL3/vG5e995fL3vv2TT7/9Fbi/D/c32Psbf1TO4/Mnn/7qH1z@7u@B43@C@0/h/uwnn/7mR@ym9h/C/V/m3H4Y3nPh2M0BrK/95NNvfu8nn379O3D/Tnh/5/r9K58tv7/95dU3xvvmH9wc5hv/Du4/ZLCisN/4XeaG72vhf5eF@/p3Ln/937P/n4c/NP7e5a//EB@h5Ze/8@f/5fLj/6iqpT//N5df/ubllz@@/PInl1/@l@rlb/4bRZ5//MHlt//4r//kD//6T/4V/X@fPv/wTf6X3/nlv/o//@r/@qs/Ce/P4P73YPrsr/4jNOO/@@Pv4v@bf/x3f/pd/P/vv/93f/ytv/vav6aG32KGf/idP2LPH338lR99@dd@9PGnK55fufH56Ru4f/pP4PLm@XwTOG9Srs/r8unPlJ9/DDZmqQANAOX@4uVvfhWI99ehj7r8yvdxDwjcK/7fVxUa5vvM9v8Bg3q9zOgjgwnub11@5RvkfcTS/wZYgj95/33ond4Pe/X3338/xOAn6Afu71NHdi1GZJ6R78znEzILB9Xw24Q0nj9v4ZTxAmhq@cmnv/Y9akuYlTqdDsRev6SWMhugtm2Uy/E84SaG/2oM8guzX2IRUr6kOY5TDXPwCXKxhcQ@Qf53@d2PLr/3Ly@/@1uX3/0a9v9CrpzdyQrKa2QeCJh/g3AYsPAm4TAgJN/O0PFSIQNm81zCTUrb54RUoRxaSWvOgptSr7dRgR@BR6WycZYVtpqkwEp8QePiLieQbRVBvZXZWpOIome1DU2HgFKOhSMVZ1vOZYobui5x7XMJd0SRczJnlBQWUlJDXDIvXKklhZAlRY291iMAcTG4RAazm6ES0UYkp@U1MsmEJZmEU/PoDoEmG9Q4IWwqZUK9J9yEzuBH/5lxwpEMFZLohV@9iozUEMaLZv@LcIcFyUNamdlsDZUeCRPcNpgLXdhAE8@BJkXnQjOTWh0NONcAXndAb6nVMhixxjIFVpa/eonQ/GQyNSg8xmZxsu0SgpjcoVAgZo3ioTZhETMIrx7hJMOhE81NplS7CwnWJnfRIYPAKdjnz2v1Um1SR3CvGFIyk8wdmicEVstM6q/AXqMwIR6XuPsKslKqZTL1EiaIhWR1lG2zmsrTwtGy46w6qwh449K2rW1CbvFKiWczVmuIMBYan5lZaAyIUQ6e84rKP@dzqsxD4GZmIywb/UdGem9Q7K/RdMMkWdkx5TUKjLSfbzwPA9KQkJogiKJI4MZlJFtkm2xxDGuZDM0MvDIhEimxUOKIHQjFFJehtc7QBvDBmX4blKhqrgr6SZWgk2dw@CkxujZJ5tYnuO7sjIQysxx@H/OC0yFMTta4s3M9XJe2rpMLcCpwGIKmWdv43BdmFrG2vr7OJeq8xj@m8@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@Euek8dKiTA5VjBkGhBqKVS5GhyAxKsYABHrPPoWlc/XDvCCAfPSaKKovkwO1YkKn6@2QiEgJc4MAdmm5WuKCxkScdWUMXQ9g4@dAPBuv4iVm@KfNzCFpvsDEhVdPgqeQKWSVfbK2t2WcCwmlSojnDtaEXYD0TECdvwUW4tzjyFjjBJVwQzh2ZDglnRvYfVxn54hZlkoLcHwYer@SBM6Q5nAAK4XGj@auKWIemtjiVyiXWPvggIPX63qO7wv49HL2YDEi0slSwuuJApKTTHXsm9e0T0rXetXD7hNi1/JGtT6EdA8I26oCRAOe5ExcXFz2AuX@PqHWVWlncLj4vDOrSAfPFROcI8Ogel7gdDdhwxduVSu2VkitC3iqVV5qqcuDAbUhcwuqtAbnRtUEbEvvxTi2nyBklnOVxSJrn@aoPmdK0krTBJRSeh5emaRxtQ4SrmByha8deybWaELL5nEKXjnF40r0@qanxFYad3JqF1WQWFn3Ag/QDj8iRX5H5hbaoZ4Ci4GJq@rHTaAxTvn1bw2ErLSfHZScUNeQC6nRdy2m0ku6ZToB0RtC3lcgVw8lJKGcrwdlmQLo1MCeaWHCaLlucjh@c98kYQhZywBRPK6pC14lXcmouwRMMjaxSK8lcopEAHsA1WsAL/pf/Wg2uNfnn@we0NBo1bgK8dP4OnTEMfYcXxz10H8/@jx8P5603/oeP3YeP3aELf@gtHyKTr87@1eqC9eZ/yFuRvVarkNXAnAC9wS8n58H6D9/@6O9//T/8/W98IuIV2mKHf/j2t5j77/wqPr/17b//1i/8/bd@g7r8yt//zr8Kvf7hd36f3AUmMH2pI21efv3jy0//6PIHn11@/NuXP/gTtM7/P/23odfH35o5ghldrvy/Rf7mV/7z3/72J3/92Ud/@63P/va3/vhHH31dLSk/@uiX/va3PvvrP/0aAfuPf/jVH330tb/5pY9/9NEvQrj5/49/@Enk9eXYEczgcv0P7gCX@/@vGy9k0Ljagy5g2AyP/qzTvQgNpZxr7QGPa5DWZnQqaB1Cb7JdjwSPdanxSIBSYDE3vu6bdk/EFf41fnNU12SV3wyPFq@Td00H@5Awfr1b67oG/TB4tSta@IF23N/H4uVyfNV18ADAWjSjD5JG@qxfO6X79qtmrS/iUTOeo9sQveN2p6IfTEFINFzb9WpJUHmTIGe/a7k2pWIw73RdB2VYp2aCmoWTDVualqtA@cSRO9pS80WBCA1FBsETb6WU7UI/6G1B/1tRs2vmVrFY6YqGbereVr6SR28jXtuxlZcrffH9hw/uB8HoACQm0w@2cmWIgMe14cFKW6VKPg8sheczDZpiC794zAQMYW0N@mNT7wrwxqUfvqCWWhWafq2WTG5piiooFU0ucWFhZwhzqo6QUwpbciWYRyPZsy3H9bI8hx9mjWsBK3Cg1HNyblOCN4G6x3UoIE7VyY7ZN7E/ojWnbEojpAkwQlAdjB0w5jelDhgtMJY3JQuM47qmyJvSGIxGPaeAq8GoBGuDWN0apIkly2C2s0gu2YFyFsoXFcd1zAuuktWz1hmtuUqv17vYOMvMLCSxTdeeq1fWnp@B3nYmsHBQ2xeCnu2cxdaqMIPAVcg4K1gzT3DRe0A8Z@GCnAqv5kt8tVGd2YsFvtq64LaHZtfS8XPbTfnseqwCiIQMagISahLuouK5blDpmD3XM2cBNaUQBWQZuh4gx1/EyTVlTPHsenKFuUCTsxleY3x2bNc4DlOiX6FcllYuz19wRogOz@xesISylWzkyKJSssFqxApNPHvGJTYO3tXqdaDbs1xRzeVzeVUrFPJFFcTfcq6QLwHZyAU5r6rAPHLlUrl4Aa1Wkl4l6GfsyO5Z1Jor9EMGKb3CjvdstEj61SPLPitpAmM/qXQVxKXEKy5x6@BdtV5fPQ6XAlXiXVWo17R8GUwamlSNClWqKqiaoCmCouH/NQYV/28eXoW/ik@IpancER5@9AikeFBgHPIAz28JXHLkunSX2R3TWBFid6DTg5Z2Pdf3/xFh7ujOMfO6a7GTdmOv@zp@7s0fWsFgRYino6Hl@LhV7Z8Kwt6wAxlEbs8C3IGHZ7vusgBF8vQJPA72375/FL@Xl/phfHY9IIcdXg8xjvZ2du9zBXLn8aO7V175EFyePNi7dxRbi8w3ipqPQfz83oMHV63hK/f46UFv7Hp4c/ceP83NHrETbs7jcnAtBoqdKZDwgVYU8VBVIWskX4wMCof7Am/nyuR2aMwXZkYZje@xnYeWH28dZJtXK9xRtB1RJ9gFdEyCn8cyu3SIlh7lGI5sKMUyx42I456Soky6rm3r@P353ho4DnSfdEwT1XTbRkrEpE9dz@6eWl1zDURjSKOs4Le@MRPcfQAyHBsDTAC0JDwAuItfhselGB17bJLxiKx0hBc6odGz@gOQNE7dKADX0XUC9@e9IL45fwU3OwQsDep2zce@HpxLcDuPcQAmwfO7PH9fD3Sp@Iyg@DSo8EGe7@MEt@0H3Qaf41trW7kSMPldGUfdLaJOdUmRqoBCpXBed7eVjbbZr@ULyhb2xDU5s50olao872u6kwXumK3gCMquV3OsZ8SoOhVQ64sbhDTNczuTqykyqdCjHzwIBIyjo5P7JrQXSlyVv/nt7//4z751@dXPLn/wGyj/kbuuZ@i4hh0VcULV6lAfF@k4kFou5UtlTS1lS@VSLq8U8nlcGKkUS8WynFVkpaQUSvmyki3lyiC45XDZZL5cDLV5SdogOzYO4GWZxi5tVAC8Y@DXrzfpkJI4qHMJtsaHvEzpaZLQY/uY8CbE4cmO0zdtgIFjgQHdCrth1aDbJlBarUgAsk4Mkrh3b1e@d4/n76AFVzTuyjzfRUu@JMvFOzxvUp/dEsqmvMvilPBIRz5gFlm@A1U4ZgDwKwY8P0DLXgEnaHjeQsvuzr17mE4PLSrGh2DHzIdZ7MhShGAOWjSNAXgRQ4NgOyydHM3oHlowSfS5x3x2wY/n346ygz4HLBgDcD8q6c4Oz@8zy84O@uzSYudZRr@Ilh168bwHFmhePN8HQ9@Dhs3zHTBiI@N5A0zGVAc3/OI4HoDvBDrPTxl6EEE8P6GhdeOY59uROybzbpibPGK3Qi0KK/U2tZTxx/NqlGkMpsUWjedzsSUHZbt//119EHTNPrumHnsbUNL79zXdmoz37nXefrvT73e86c7e2wfotbt7HwSa6djr9DthxE4bLhdi7d5X9ePh9OoFpd5vtyu6vdTri@12TneueLWnbRNzCLFeQM7Cq48JDdu74LV7v72tL1v0RAG2kb8M4d3B684Q3nf0DvOKLupF35NOh69CMwA1ppniUPPCdUvYPI@BXzvZoW54bhXtkxqR6VL6aaMgt6rUgwxBdZKrF@jfS@FTx/H29Nm0ManJrdqkVlTZKFsvxTcnat7is2vDLaWcr6zpW4qay0wquKTO7SVJUlC2SEq5vfGSpB6lt1RQoNb45taWwDeU1lah@GxjDBWPjy1VKVVyskrSzKoVKxBHTsqE4CPdKLa2ivnKLHKxmNEltVIsgugH@AlAgOjgAHebpFKnpn6cTmPW6QAplIcWnExpoa1qLzXJTmosk2Sark5qSpWdGk3kK9BSqS5@imBs4JE1hAHtA8AJaFC4JDHFK@USD3mQJFy3icN2DDlnObl0cXbmn501L2JWKYFpNkT93peOjo@O3gduBRLJlI3s1cPB3SeeiTwvWgX/9v1dcf9xZMOvDIj3UDh2PXEXedyCD5OSI6cjUKLE@9CtgwIduUGcwHNtcY8umwcJO/KIjvoRw5OAxaP7C3AOB@4pSxki@VUU4nQ8PwE/wmB1iV6rg0nvkhTNFdHTp1SgaNfrtXZtaA5HwRSKGMX6IqFfKJiB2fdZ3ulHYfqmR2j0s57nDkOPdk2@qHZqk8REEMgOyHdjLwsQ2zUiKM@Hbve5mjGqXfwKw53aHQRTbcO7UzVrpue5Hg8aLF/tbTm1sePrPfOJ6eGhEPuP10HQwTNVUj1iptdJcw9D76JedSHUPeLM8vhoPEzpQr2TXnTCCZHYAdGU@lJU/DOcEICc8/xFtVcjqWcQ9AXYvXWS6op30lu5KmDsDmmnwUl@3nveIyop5KpUDUohLGiCFFOIAT1dq38R5DMG@hh6b8hNWOXHABUTA8BQG9RHT4@si6pRs0lKIJM0xVGu2q81MPo5PjYFnm8JQuO8hfMZ76Fu8GIMnWcdmnt1mtBr/rhDv8tD5I6iyoXqBNyUYq46gPrWn02qXm009syqDdZwBoTQEutVwC2gEMC8PE9dfvWj9KaQrzG3KgV1jsPWbbFdm1QdPFEVKKWm1cAj08jJ2TyupM0XsyBCqIWsUshq2VxWKKIryA90PwWqYa21tZSd4gnhs/JEFpWsYirZlPzc6j5PZ49TKN9Q5KWzgbvnjIcEXaDKkFqpHd56OqNuAIq6LtE3BUq8wGSqWC7A/YCMrOyAQjowdZtFSAtE20jZ6ykMtH40Hu01WpXK3mT0JfBKCS@2CpminHmZTldTa@mab76gs0V3LCAQHZCLnIkWf7QGNB3OEhF/PGxArYNJKaqVRqODZS3KWU3WoJhW@7y/ydf5VlZeKyhQZxd0MkAhjLPMz4uA5MTN3EZt1BNsE@pQKatVjm4jSZA73phO1GglVShL@Y28zCZHGAhuFLJIxC1JNaMdN8lUMllUk8mZUp1OVnEieo2fzQtSVfuMcsgksGySvK3mC1s8CIB8hS@rPASbcVzMJZGjnG@AHGr6uocTSBwOVZAcqOpn3MXZxWadm4jc3tCyLT1LHMvAD9xZxrHI3XO9bpZ0rD7p6QG2ZZHbgdLuV0TuEPQ8k5oae/iRA8Li0@NQMForBFihs2vBYDowQRkSuSmdbAzE665QSwTfUVKLIcgXuEM8TWNTfYa/4rOHO4/xd287gbtTyPYXwK8M7qVnD58@fvr4Hj0xYbaR@fNc2xyR6BaUidiuJqp0zB9XZkAyWLTK51jnvY3z70Raw6MASEYUxDo9bmKbpdIMDz6S1gj5vHtkMpv1Z@zdxK2gAJqjJ6w3SIuuEjctVNPJuzoIlFskCVWue8OGqmqthloEsQS6robMgqqqUoVctBN0X3Md6HtyBpnezNTxUIkvkulUzwhR0W@Tej@zLqvTxEmbL5Q1eu5Bu67Ix2QteXsDPx0ukMTJ8Vpd3cgkn1S0TPJuUsslTlLN9XpGmSYlspFRpz1co4aroaQkhFPNjVvaRvJpplLqZytKBp8qPCtJIqwlttvZ7XTZ5yglk8QCgtfKO7Wd/sFOtHx/Z7deUqfhYRiJZ22@VAyz2FwHlKmZZ9sL8esgCz3Dmdsr9fazLOrfxkXwyWoycZYkieRF8qKRbAHoRiM@W6XWmmUfl/SF6x60XIGkEyQd2orlhJ@KFx18IbmdSOLMPvH9V0DQtB5os46OPfjicxWYTMJxIwd3HOAoL4hR@TzOWyek5yP/A7WkPdx/7Nz17plcorl2vubimgRS5RlInrxy3vkS6LFQW0nSrCUmtVw48avU64KyqeJRZ0VSAQGgpxQE@bzOOFmdehRU8Ln86ndyk80S2FVZAbuq5jNqva5sgAiaGF1@@oPAm5KzvXd3HpAkTiP/@M@@pxZ//Ge/T5fOJy/o1LKqFRMQEo1KoZg4OxudnYEAeMH88olW4toywBagSVL0cnFDrFaIVCqVN8S2lGDoBFG5qKQTvpAIN1QU8kIqpUhqekMryWnwOQ@Pk0qpcgms0RIP6sQX8nw6sXdg5VVle3MLSral5dTqWqPBK/FoOIl/m6ZfTnCJ0sPn54SAxah3@31LpSZJCtvQK4FsvhI24Q01/EpYI89rdVzLqOAhLtFqgQ08AAKX7yTrGWkjSUDPJvXGRfWilaFLDuiox7MNp3kFGc013DG86LThwM/c8OnPNKmVOvhgjWzmxoc@n9pIS1K3S/scXO4hCPUEI9m2SfJ1oJcNCXK5Ea0QYD9BaKYvv/qbqlr48Z/9ynn7vP2@qqrlcrmgqImf/nRz7Ix9s1v/KUR8Eh3cB0RkWF0k1iP32HR8MR5voB2d5eAHziwnHqcg7IxJK4wVG0SD5xJjB3UxFj4atcDxCQLyqNV3zC4dreBOUJqm1dpmR@V1UzTYBgFlJEt1OXo2V7rKcZGew3Q1r29kKQyygedRN1pp7ox7C71wayzoe1XurRkocBiCNOYabd8eeyO60zpF4ymtLLkNUSCFt/AYwjUInSZhny0AF4Z@@lpUlmWfYo3K2wSPTsdDDUEU4d6CKOH5@faUjHTPN2lIywE5QcQgNJ/Uo4u7pVqQts0itKlripaeBcgSljsWyQEVjnsLZEuKBQtETmJtQoAq8JS3AAFQhlQI2GqRTaKlyZmVyVRnJyZe4Pk4jgsojI704zAaQusCmuLIVQwHTqA64keCkS7CGga@N@cYAWEw2Pq9GiifGJ3aUJi3gBwmbwwKYJ0OsIZo0cjt27Nc1WpWN01oiRD@sTXCsVpaD87yvAKwSIu/BSwVxKlMBiv7rUWyA4xnaHaB6gR2CGV1Lirh0XrBcfB/Y6JFirxSVdSjigUI64u1CgNQBpER7awODbJZI4paTJM48wbk3aCZogc@xUMTzcktUX0/8ryAHP40EX3vC5jV0fz4d0i3d037fHgeI9wnoICN6Rm4wUBnzKBr2tYQFwbiaDUyvf0gih3HgqJYNg3dszxQg@kywegkxJSmpDHa7ORImg@6nVHNEdxrmE/ji8bC0ATeOp7MF6azRkVXw4UK9UeuQ4/yC5A14a5OoAjgUZDAIzcwWbbHzil@hC@sGxp5PkdQStBykPIxx/RoQtcxfRYXV9t1PFM/jnCTJWZfJMawS9QySVFCc3BZiRODS9NINMMd0J4Qxx3bHEKWDk2THnjgVySpD0LfuINz4tJDC@hqcM@C7sfxpbsMwdKpdWxJR3jguuD28FwEChyggJyIzY@t1wNFc2x3ie26x8S2jk02rZGaPxYRv2tSyILikwXMzm5AbAVFXlXL4iCYkmWh4C7Cq8iMpexc3LXUNH39rSlrqTbW6DntwSyoFds80Z05/NLrnAsHUvypz9FTIGsEFYcU2MWY5ULLZAeqJfGMw2RaBNx3QcKi9etDFIwp4nTZKMUn@LToj2wroEZu5JknBAdCOOxjgGka7TAL2IqhtG/RDoC2PWhZeDJj4FWg5jKQE6@bMqDphQzeIbeIpnIYEFLGoCwDAAOrvrYIHfwgKpbDD7pQMSKdI0K@Aq1z2AU/PPktJD@MH1E3muk5mTPyJmshOOx0aFo1wppFZMnPWbB1ID3Toq@BZwFyuCQnayk@A2AzfJpnoOP4V6MzaucoL6mQ65CyBCGEqAYoVFTQkeXgMdRzX9HDRSR3dODO@KEEpHog@tPTU5EeQjr2LNH08ctyvuvotjTqWyAOu1JgDkfht7ctQxpFcGcmgX04UhwNRlsTFGpr5dtT9ua4nl8Ll9@mkj0/iZ3jCX44rT88Qd0KMtzzKUHds@jHFY1UuByY0Z/ayp5F9FdJ0hP9khcIhBAEM8lOs0YWgGU7xnG2d9qthh4ntEECcKhFM3LEo4G9yDL0I5M16sUh3AD5aOz1/7b39ftpI8mif0dP0cHJgGzx5dhOBhvPYoMTdh2TAziZXMywMgjMDCAGYRsm4/M7D3Hf477KeY37FPfWR7fUEsJ2kvk4u785eyYWUnd1dXV1d1V1VfXl6CfyJwBICT4tCJrmHqqSS/VT/p4O0W9/4tyK0mxmL1P03cTSyMCpJYk9YgnbPn2BR9hmxCfOUztctJbtUPWFXx02Nd@jCBbyFO5c9wLlpMX4fcHfF/B9wd8XQaOq2daizSIZvrrD7iDXYwCCKolglqrMHSf4Db4QZJDDRZ5BYMll6B26KXeLVFvRm3/BOBYVYwBPTIHgTirb@uGiddGeeM7tZnsrOwBmTxAhYMQBdKtNNL3t@c9I/dHNaOp6oVewfZB4I/HGV90ryQ3MK9hHf4CIMZheQ0zKOhhLTycWCGSHAQLKYfARRYPSPDU09/0s2fQRGKeVCGjMiLUkMm2SvuQn@Q7EJSY9E1YH1NYA4Xu/S4AmfBFq5vA9omp1@DBzoYwqm6arD2GJXIpkOwmUjEwVXmv2aZA0rNJphSaQHcXVYrQr6jsMRSvySevmnRx/Hf2nn41@H@ZFPPbEsLxh7Bv6VMFgAxAh5HQhqorDojaugEF20x45M9i5Kiyfyt0amtnMKjWD28EueLfDefcqpQ1@1@TxoawWiUmi4LPCsliELi6LPC15XiiSMsH9ap6stlSMIOvzAgIwcrHVHFltoVdbFIu8cIjFmmq3GpILQnLBVbj0Yg2SbVkNtKeq2l5weNognWIURALg5XkbBTFomhCefeOgB8eP1@MpalWqzWDNIS6QPIQiNvJZtx3bektDWlu0IgCQEVcA9PiK8YIRXfDyaf@Xv0YxKdUaxb8kG/BaAQxGS/C@wTqQz2SkA4PAn9iifQDmbmKrZSTydEyA/8vxfwlLvVT/5Vdf5sIl8@GXOSvyv9/lZRspq01QTfrI53ZwQTYCS4VusnjrgjYY2CE0hwntFR4Uhd/BAjChYqzBjRFKihS3e80LZF/gKc7sgR9JigpWTliipD7GC42VOPcouTc1Iiix2y3oGReThLmv3S@grAzBxijESfW0IjYp4KVPgrMSmhOzBEspjMbT4eQ@BOhkjyRvnERktXjuFeA/wMFSIIFMZL9IEW3MB3Ejilxe91uUGUtOBOJTkcrr2CCCfVCOJ3i0biWeeyJhfQMVTWTcSu3ENMKJ@uURSag@IOdNJymoZSXSmQRVhXeYXgYhhUHwaOJ7hTCgjLKpUsRQocDb8zJ0a5CzgK5MBg4pZnY2/yq3961BvZtYc2vc@rZtbXaLCQFLkD0Ze9ez295PA/fqpi9GYvrj5aK7/OVnIXZ3BGbx3P6GAzHze8UshY1RgK74NkdXLEgEv6NQU0yRnlHm7KSgyxU4cuGpoIseBPkpFFAmjHCp2BwrLkSjwrw4bu21ixNYhMetSXsfzRrzreJ8K7@Vwhff5E3MoIQ1U93WvA10udNm0abx2gatBi/0FKVLjw4@YU8zQuaCOeyQHp7A0sEF3vI0GoKgT8x0SwqpjBIEZQUYNoCo37JtVPuo2VN5C5@keg@VMqKGkG@HKJT4Hzy8E9CjHRaPV@d4YwCAxKMukDAoYT/ssi@2WWl3BPYIS8GuPdCRwBFHcwxOf/8agIwhr0QwuKvUFzSO4YXMAhVXPPGHnbpgGP9xPez@dPxabOdyL/O5F3mNZHgLLyKYy7zYCbYrIJL6sI0uPrv5HcM4dqdLdtmDzRxh7aQRoCVOUTl@D3qZc@NMJo5RGo3Yt8/Dmyuc2Y3TyxhG3emR2@jlNVEE1bhrJBdote71rMvXHVwOJ/ZsiXyBd7HQBQkw@fEv@iSOQdXpy2sHLQOtIKCQjYdztpW4N0O8VsS3/PTd0ci9RYJ10ejC9MBKYwf2OGPTFGGUkFgKF9L3x9feHKc0Wo0RoH2Jl@R2fTJMYPPrwsiQCcMYASgy3GmNTXoRTKC97shGVSsThwA0pFFAIQBd6113nXtxMAiJz8RByI6pUA1bjUzWnRkuzZWxjaotyHUBgWlUqJqGOwxw8021IRq1k@aHUr0i4Pldvfa@Wq6UxdFH0XxTEce1dx/JIVe8qZ2WK/WGwIjW49pZs149Om/W4EWi1ICaCfpglM4@isr37@qVRkPU6qL69t1pFaAB@HrprFmtNCxRPTs@PS9Xz15bAiCIs1pTnFbfVptQrFmzqFVVzQjqidqJeFupH7@Bn6Wj6mm1@ZFaPKk2z7CxE2itJN6V6s3q8flpqS7endff1RoVgR0zytXG8Wmp@rZSzkD70KaovK@cNUXjTen0NNLR2oezSh2RD/XyqAJYlo5ge8SWqJ/lar1y3MQOBU/HQDxA8NQSjXeV4yo@VL6vQHdK9Y@WBNqo/Mc5FIKPolx6W3oNnTNSD1AFxuX4vF7BkyikROP8qNGsNs@bFfG6VisTrRuV@vvqcaWxL4zTWoMIdt6oWNBGs0RNAwygFnyH56PzRpXoVj1rVur183fNau3MhEH@UMFbX45LULVMBK6dcW@BSLX6R4SKdKABsMSHNxV4X0eaErVKSIUGUO24qReDBoGITb2b4qzy@rT6unJ2XMHPNQTzodqomDBg1QYWAJjY7ocSNHpOvcZxArz4EZjVUJxr0XCK6okold9XEXNZGjigUZXcQmQ7fiNpnkHnWk1AG@JFj4491oW2/uqrGwcdwlalvXj5zz9/Oq6VKyKhzg0TwYdz2HVeRQ6m9G@w0/gf4WfoAKDnXF4POnjlDkrsfjUWqsbewMKMDiZGkl8Y95xTS9mNKmxsdDrvS51S/XWj0zGtx9QMofFQDUqtCsLaPaVM2UeMNUMbGgqVhQLT/SBEqMNvUBzsOzNLsBMylWTqf0Ob68Qeg66YzfYcWQ1NIQhYiaWwB8/csQBgPVwayQqLse9BkyT10O@hZAeqmFLgM90OvMaecyHXg38mvwY/eHPQXsDqzKJ0Njtw5owGKKiqGW6EDEz0j7TvgPZFkrznOD8NUjm9OWfSMzN4PxV6R8o6VHbujEaDlPlA9UtnEKmejtYnZNGoqRImexxYwNoFMiafg0mSCTkumRn1LIX/dOb0x1TYsAUNDSXUFJngpUKU@oart3JtJCsbCkGi5kFGme9t6fvqB1Ryc9s7@5H3b/z3PLfQYRB9S2HDa1G9Nv150@YCMMHIsgkkGUp7Yzar1QGxjARKv/AtFLzCQny/Fu7VVw7t60ASEGSv7ZHeJu7Gs@FCxx7W4df10tuj85MTWDoR251Xuy/39g3/EPN7i/9@xHbIu5POcKewj4OcRp@0WXIMgg/NFM0VP2B/YuBsFgtiIIcaNHqJVjP/EisWEjgHBslSB9hdDxNBTNAMknAmdPEWmTOfGopfY2emZIBUqKsm9mZsL0jEt0FWIh6Qh6ajJY3aAv9B2P70V1Pc75BkIMli5O8KnGs84XUvgZXopK3vXk/4GASLZBKKj/lQ3KcB3sol8gV5jEi/JG9rowiCLQ40zlcadqoJSDyNYiGkHkqe3dDEO7LaSuWSzmLhzfeS3@Dxo3QXIOcB25uX5g0g44lfE3XgQNGVnW5JyG0MrMMjatXSgUALgimRorknVVXfzKrNBkIFY17ROhUGvO9bZaNNoiKc/FsS9G3mVDSFIpx9ybHyN3BuXHcklH1ljZW/lY1PMCzfZMxUu/XbMFSRj75VUJEzRKavogfB/xNpEgP/ADROgB5QS3OpeBQlCSrTCtRXIsrwVhkxNMtJQE391ccAzJ0@MFd@x6RlaEGuBEgCOTpL9eIjOZH0UzEEQCY30bNAm78916FrzmFnBtXpbwlTVkcbzKQ7nqaE3CvUVrECN73XtkjsspTdBn@YwiTDrNAaPIWq4m@suF3SrAeVKaLKi@degsGZypqa3cTzjGDCE5ciRfJqsgeclZOzTK0D8uBK23B6/vkTiKV3ay2Cm0JzOAqt/dKqpggFoA8Rn9V@UoShK7oj13Mi/it8B0STfArQc9@SVydKBwD0NEAXJ4TzvCfkrYTO/BY3iBFDJ8eHAJpIPSffC2yEjyUCwUEtt2YGSEvb6q2P/YKwv9WwP59wfAn9LAhVIsM@JhLDCV4rCTxDN4KLt/YSUB49rtvMYtnNhmuJW4eieNgsIetjwGXXdWcgOtrYb8DRGi7NjPggjQ7OxLueSW8Q2M@GM2mRUEI/NINiE2vvtM1w3Aah5g1BbpijzQX5g7o0duyJdBAZLtJ7IgXMq3j0EFmY3FoWW3mROgi@HABNyMmLiHgg9jDBGpVigkoHLIcoOPR85QJmicvtHIhcMP1u3dlPuPejCDTpOT3fz0sDCS/UIFUn5DHTnXPXp65HFg0YCrSA@JTIsyHt0u7@dIuSN@zRLyU7gYCOrxKBrxF6glFPPr8dn0klVGwoYFzZOjDfXhoGE6m0LR2tfNer/PYuoRKncN2tVcbI9ypsEheJi4m/pBTk3a/PleiIT7xu@k8f8Ynv/nOKzz2cPfAG7edSBEWEUWZFm@3qOkf44XnFh6Ez6@k2UZBkevYUzW@k@rgT4kVlOpROFF177jlL0AC62eEiSzA6qb@7V5POsTuyB0N3aIOehqEVC17x8HFJjzhgg5l761EsMSdN0gr1lsEzWcPloTb@lh47@DM46PTmzjSlH4HMZ8sS5llALYaO8fGs1d@viL@n0RNnv87OblDJr0N4ZKbX3hXopvtr677Ix1Xm0wIEIBe4w8jpDB2TO@jzWFQtudOUdtyhClzeV0DD8VKkha19vluL8bdAIjrgDWGskFk58tA7gZrZWoxbvYXVI4@OmTuHdavsYMyql6LXlo0pPWEV@Q5PIQoi/yqnVaV8mb0FenXgw3I9ubdf/snYAwJfgX7@RRy3xDECLXF9ORtgTSZlQvpsAS7kzjykNZpWYljFhgPYhUYhoJ1FFGr483IdNehUEYQi6bSwwpU4I1Og@GDKi1QHlpzOkm5IT4qkSY4CKIKU6MKcdQzr6Myq@9fo7eARN4fYZXBhOpaQUxrS60jVBSphMsAQzOm1jjJ7qD48Y7a3HztqEQIWJQFDOGh5MlMJJbmgJzbfRj2nYy13BotxIkI9eSqZ9ObuNPlI6q1dO2LPueNo3TXXEelThNmKsFlu9oi0xSU@LveNKD4RpglTjE6xgYdQfaVnn82jRFwUOzjfip3lA3RYR7PgTNbfVPzx7vHcx03xBsNK1UbjTynCHV2@9v33rQ50vLN@BZEwWb3q0IrRwSWjs@RHDVSETD6VHk8h4j6Je4QePaActtsD2unjs5ao0QN45UCmPoVchpCe6AZvjx1cl6b9DHQkZarzKX@R8gXOhbWko7x8@hJdNvEDA0Sp2EkHdii24AaDFeEjirXopzroFpjHlQieDtlnV3k@SUR9glGMgzTusHtvq7NM59v7DGnhQwKtgq9pvweSfIXFWp0FQVkhBUzxGFL4PVpZm64e36uv7QuUAwhcmz5713gED9IUdsYUW4AN/KN/6ixQBg6akjVDMyo8ETq0NMBcAC1lMHJYXUXpbzhjjsebfeQ0AgWCX9PFPVuyBjpH7@V8amOVRW@JRUxJbp5tJuZJoyoBQ/FvJL@ciizqkuIKABzGGOoX8wABncQIezwUGDn9eYjzQojKMYKKxTxOS3hJPmaBD0nMdySqLLCzq5XIxZX4VoeRjgUCgkV8mQARkFniiwRQYKOLxUUr8TK@P0EJEIgV7zPFYSjkqIRp6I8cE5By6OXMYEVp5YWVkxxMH3d2zdBHn7/p67c57Wsu@hXo42PYSuejX1/lQl9DzW5vh6uGagI9TL3V0Ecghakj7K8KX/d/BrkEag7kSsI90JSMkJQhfb8wxyFomaC3ZX70xAGaOA6VjKHg0WFcOk@qolK/OhywFnJxv9@dXSTpyAA94b@6typmQ2EiIy@SFxNytGfjLiuEJLEmcKvHbqGmS94UaDghjxPQb5VO6/bF@@bJia4Ei8ulcjQaO7PdXC6HTHyphxIovy00JQ3dbLh0tn89GmWnt3@fvb/M0tqP2bJHnltQGrQDQwKTwsu4swHH2SAOUBRLp4HAY/fGQV3/ut/XA1rwhBIHD4aNS7KvWE/QBjT0nV7eNzm4/iTYYP@JHcT@/VP4s@/WZkFTQlHHUFAbqHdxk1CnZ0AefNFH3y//pIqA4cKsvJlg3zKLh59wB8E4MRoscgY10Swk2T/xxhmNXEt8wGxkTxNkUYlUODnRK@S4CJ4wIlHQxWgEHGYJ52Y4Cs6nPCyi8zqCUxuTitpRXvYYaVB3BpXFNJVo/ZCAbQW6vIXd3EJvX0skBglTut4/AizzIaD9qNJje5rqEp2ihWGrlzM4eAKMXuStWN0nVMQkm5ik2cOlkajx6GZ@dIeTFHTdJFlARQbQ8FJP1hT3iZu4WOT7SMMcw5A40R2Bj6pxt/91S@PXLYs3837/casiBVXwwH7WishxZV@3INIZAM1AOf2Anhhd@Y80TOuTSCAUCzgY@rS67mCFDlYwjOfd4s@3qVKpJJ5Nt7ZEqXQED5jk56gkyvji6EiUMYMK/v6muL27u89rbtn8BC@P1Ms7cQQw@C7i7tWsDD/hWxED3GC7Jy3yWbb4zNp/1ikeHO572VbpqJ3NDuCJ75bKluQPvHQqe0Q/Wj/4hTKZTPZZ99Ozb@728Xer3E4@u2w9m7aTg33kMiBD6XruVudpO3AfzcwujQ3eBbS35Eeq9GwPs7jKqkKlRxjbs59gdSmIja6X3ZBvPY7DpTV2o@to750JJkEBFV6FcERVeQND5Mf2Es3xMDpdBx3wYL@hFK7kB8r1@WxFGe4nrlbAP1XZIASkzHrjAGg84VhCJ7lhjB/Ay5adCVrAb0jm5e4Zhg1/h/OO5N/sD/LOh82LlNjMiU1LbCYS9Afvf9i8MJ9lh3ivCBfzb4YIjhbQzVB4QxL0SH@gyMUIuQ3jGQVAIiQVDk2FJ9fjSzQ@K@0Pwydl@Lo3MJ7Q1aNsIqFDJqyy8enZ5A6G5ROUuEsYTyicMY95P1hQ6EgthhrTTlT88UURyPbYESBoecwEKbjQJJ70QWU@88uqN3KsDYrNJMBI1vrrE5r3@AL2omcU05mP6FIYNErBj/wW98Z9Dt4ltPELtx8gQAcqrE7mKGwkuZHEsw66WsDvJXVTUIyn3j/JfOzrsHTmWDFo/j@FxgT06YlOuGcTekfnmPSR6Z8Y@scrWlMJLkvR9nwyY2hVxtej@XA6kmdeRCIcOb@1O55JOKIEiOFwBHVhdYaRoQAzH9w6FIasDwuHHi9Fz8Wu80yQqVZxOpgZPjnSiJD9IQVz@9fI3DazQ8REsQPzACHlu/L17eHIQ5LPVc7WgT27xFwLlJ9ZDOd8bkb2PMypE8HY7ftIZwgyuZwH8xm6sjGd2YOxbYmNM7c5s5dV2LZA8pl3Myb0cJKcExI4@WTTcd1TCHOP5JAQRfyukOcQRm@PljLYnMcWR4MGg4ZUTQWZoAEnQYidiJLOr6GxitAx4OrPGAQd5ZXF2z@NlEssrbzoaSQhBV2Af2iarUwdQ7Wgzx1/4iQMRtWfmYoXZKVr3GjHdPALKzkm9FZtU01Hng8KWC6xfdydBs7EDm1O05FhcGKSZ9l9wfsizmdK7MHeSPK@ovzLfJA/ALECOfKH8G3BvDe5fZbZjCep1JMLTwbHb@j7CArPGd8XP2sjq8qzcgoHH1NCvvPJkBfLyA41ZNoDE2ZElTz/AUJ/ZA8Av@WtvURWvNhIffc0a7Z@uJi0N1MXk18vfjEJE7kkq102LTbkYbZaseRcgZ0xa4V@Kq80D0iAuRPFxSRc4GJCbl18ei9JAIhkU60fsu1fs4DQxYZpbmYvNpggoSFDTLL3t5dF8NkVNDfCWGQ3jCfmpqkGP/Vd3hSwt9JfHEN@YfJfwEIplWSmBz1n1gdQFANEdxOgYpd9tZ3b2c7vgCY0cBbpmXON@23au750FiBKeKjOwtZz8UuIG0KEuFt49j68XEA/h4MJpoGmEfVkQgu5hMppTu0YPltBnQzzBJQHKqeQBBjiYvplbDx8RIXfEsByqixltGDXQY37Urh/eu4Y27E9XNei0SHMkehlwD4iZEJNI2TJeGs51FTTJUnBZhlxfOXAICMQGN7shrZbTNxJWgprZia5j0I0Rs2MMK9vdI6uTNHQDH0mhankU5E//O7lf//v2s8b843D7eyHGfydb/y8sfdqgx/hAX69UL9uNg43DrDY3t3GMgs6MDy@/O//A/UP/w5w8MvyAP453FWw9pYbh@kiVfl143APHvLb29Du//2v/4I@PGONDTPbPOtYghDbVxQ5tifEu/BdVLGXrJYmg2UljwsLwmAPQ9DN4Qc6Ri22X@XITLchvSpu0P1n2J/7/ihyiyfHrDm5CrElQ/lTgGTEFYrYQJpBKheKvtB8N5TbBjJvgKb45/PMngcawD@lO4ffpO@68dxDl6FnrBbBAKa4RdDn@eEw913Cd@8oJJRPyb4SIVG1k2vtqxf7wA7vXGc@7Ia9JNR0HXftW@cyg3yYcXrXoFNNvJH74yx7Ayw5zm@/yvbRuJ8lP@7slCClp8vMLyAIymwkoBiS06klZjAC7hj@wjPmKAGB/sQ/k1LZOUDKnjpdtmGFMzxBkUazXKnXLT4exu5kAlE6Rf@CAI95SGRaDS3y/GICNWv1gkhs@QW5HOm8JmLzjpxjZdKRNHvDUvZaEGCoD2gdVP3JlGYDCkKiWjOAwEUydq/XseW3lPEkoQLPLePJlTOaFhPkGwa9wVvVQEKX9Gcxcy2U9BAtCOk0LXQIa@zMbVDRiwl6g/p40MIcbyfgs1bSjWl18cnal2WlVt8rnuCZ1j1N33LTtzCiKCUE7fg8E@TCmQi9GK8tRTRVzpwOHqnFNgyteSoF1ixDfxADj4el2sewBNkdioAEqgXdkV5l@rBZpAsDj9w6HLPHpkXOA2ZsBMGPlioBnFU9y6DshO1muDFYIM7ciVNAD2W@/Q4jIIoqactwQgLQymcVOyzBUB9qU4fRVITCjlhyW5rAfkgCB8ZSCiDB0PF4Uwt8sA3ePXzQEo6W0CeBhpeEiSzVL5CyRQXVcBQoqRY3jpoZ26laXeEn6@nLXEB0rxu@SOTy2y92dvdevvoWY8afyN7Gg8FKGdQCplc2wCCJOgVKNr4vFhPJBL/ChF6rTSL0OLB4AIduXbcmYcWPT/FOAQaWSxCsW0pMxdWluZJABhBnTgZ3BNBRUrNEKvVdoYUda1/0zF/hv4SlajPDoanZHg1/sZn02ji844AISnM0dsbuDI/HcWG2KbML5tSHLYS/6GUdt1938M4q9HVltoeGTl0XgxJm7vXgSueODFv7RRMmDBB8PlsWSIN67XCkKOnUGlYoi0qDQ1WLvigqeK3VHqBTLm4JKPMxcJhmMBnQy9@WnqY4O5KwCWGeB4xYxSNEzXVUZ2fizokrKmflKGIyE9rQ8@FmdM9WEO5gPwTwldoJZj7SutsE6sKUGMheqzXJYoM@6b5ygcthOeAKZHqMle5iWi@NKmqtJrlhnrqPLHnixaGf0C6oCuOIeMXAzOceJqWKa1W9QIKohVBak/xFzPLPc3SSBTjpg4zzFHk5UdB8RN8OPY9yecvGEqb0KKVCMJAen0rEAUS7TS7BHckVcETpsUJprHi0@bJXcpnE@1F5gH1N1YktOexLUwFFjXNmEZ8W2P/q2bElyhX45@RD2UJB@aj0D@y3nzBrPb55iW@@IKonagiIoNIMRz636DP1M4YoAbPkLE5fEiCIiy8ZNrAeSd5IwUr1RNKeJ3UrNLfbAVcgu9pSCFfWUTlJMGsK2UCeSOWdTGcy16JU6AtsvFpdabZkYTUt2MR1/8TWaPIkaNWHxKR8BIjtKIi0AhFw@5OA4dkDnSRvW@ouirGrJ/E8HWJZVqhAbD/JAtnDPLuWMvexxbZki@0CjuN9fEF8ey9v8L1lYeZ4gDeefhlvpB/PHOl/C@ao/Dnc8UJyx4sCrj3MHZPuzKEViSI6KamdG8Mxl0vagzu94WCI9qG@9hM7kbM0ALTg0XVkNsWD5HPYtzXLiUjFf9iK7kfoJLS9u2d8Yed3ZOd3Crjm0mPZ@Z/a@fRv3Pld2fndAu41MSMvRTsZ/vrb9TgQCVPhF7HDi@IuFzO/tKd7sqd7BdxNY4b5D@9p@nfq6UvZ05cFzJjABw6cwvV@bmZJpNQ4rlYDd4uMykCcwqyA8Vxpou6FV2Jboj@69q6KKK2LL8b/lcT/Fa5G9FRHstpajLKvy7N6ysHyLFnypXkYZMU94f7KUC@9v3LDCvQRuUHxIk2GrZlUVEAgt/hjcNqUCeTHYPX1N5/H4sxrO@VW4sywmgLNGmHeDKY4S75UWCVgfcKMPEdL2nGzfrr1v5gMY/snGYUGyOPQ3uIdQ3In0VUwHCt@LTujdQdhN6TOEWIVSU5Cdi6jvX12ebJ@VaPEFpF9MV5J4KM2TpeMGagczQOITEZAm4ysr7QqdM1V6gW/gb5zofguyx5/EZd@K7n024KoS8VgHalsafCTvBjoadu7u/ftAVwrg39wAuYsKH/PrPp/weHCqvtHqY/U6bx1PG9DSxZl6Hm6uYzAMiJcpnQNZWYFvC5mcon@B@/95FPbhpZtGZQVzzCO35YbaLuwL7s9pz@4Gv7403jiTn@eefPrm9vF8pd8wjBUcv6UyVkLlfeNNFOs5mtOzBKRpM1pLWtzAAIN80m2moQNIcl8Pmm2CoXttilwfo45HxOfDwQASESdeCO8I4ncLPzs4TSU7MEQje316Ojfm2PMOZAsNbLHlz1bLAoC/a/TeUugN5h82wVCAonIDpPqwuo5NU2T7oSRV04kdciFpKX/1Ls6G4yrbJ8TiYRECX5W6UAAjS1@Ud9C0yKTS1tsAvPxl2EvbClhm4xfU6bWQ7VA8un2TtssAJk@0Bdk@Ct7NOcTwdQvpu8J48z9SALcOo95kcNdJGeGAhc0pA9oA/Q7ZkrmCE65uL/auhr6rrXjw2gF4NuhwiFaaT@2YOr7oTsADKaCe@S6o1McX9WCJalhiVdBZ4JMiBjW/MYe9f1RUNmKh@xUGeKdcB8phyxSOzQwEUJIYvT9lS4Ipr7CZl1pKfbr42EDYHxJ7goroHR8sdJKgRUuoTU0lNOHNo1oPR5eb87pxGM6ETBny0eCckQH/Ka93xDf1@ow@jf2bIiGLba25aGNjJOB@Tkgh/@5nEyxiYrk5NrehXnlQ6YZZq4gF9@ndSinVl@C3itfYgO07mAH8OJc1QXczQaU3fBhpB@B8j3TOcShDBbZ@wS2I5@9FVPn96RQl0wi0lJ@jJt2Ye5G1p6hj3HqVWSwFR1weu0hudSLNssrwedXOM6Ycwz2gJnN7mQb4nw@hEV8Gfg0k3BDDmO6lEVJiBgY5@aPTuDulSUu5Q@ZX0diqi0eSBvK039lBonG13ROAWuxO8aWeIln7sQQPkQQ4HAG5M24FREb839mxba5vrtQCvvprQqWkS6HBjW@u@61jkDuwX4G5dUT7CH6Or5CiGE7zAKrENRSK12HcW@Qn1Y5G4@kOh3M/dPpUKqVTgflh04nya2wMKEJQdq9F6XL3vUsPbOvxrY9@Xu263lpvHR7OjeMLpD14EAkK2flJIZa@Z8y0yWMQ3ozLWSefkEiB74xEolwlOlxoyEax/Xqu6agbwaNSdcdjRwpHkgZqTbr4f2g5WF3rsQmlvLUr7GNaYUMupBSHHteg3DhHuLgdjro/t/ppDxn1NdGZyN4gv/eNN@eiiYlHGxWGpQPsRFTFGFkMACS1FNE/OBpuXbc/PiuAlQcjw6NA/UHCh1SvYP5cD5yDg@y/JffefMligLLqQNaoHyXpZdQN8uVDy7d3hL@9IY3gj4VE@rovzBzQNwa3jj7UFmnLSHYd915gGAW6iNQCS3LCKoKemUQ5GrlmigIu4dHNiAIKuUBJ5WHgSHD/lIkXyQzQ4/0@pQZblnefCKl0ST/zGCLSUskb7eSMVt/eCAab0pAy9entaPSKWb8elepYxrLdWNxOegA06AES9cyJMNfOTzNnYSECvoylxJr9GO41PckGofffQy/W9ONeuV1FfM5rsecSVoUn3KF/F340w36VMV@oUso6NvdKgZrUDk5Lb2@FwtU6lb2PfqKFubYr2uaqp29rmEKSkydua5FdzIATWPQwZZjyKs@Y9MdvKjDexS9VctHtfI9NB@MuDPRRrExnB6Pauq4dn62fnGQLsL5MJQNw0f0vPnuvGmEa/qLFUwYWqcssdCWKm1qSZ@UhbkO/lGpURGVU8p4qn0iX5eRM1bQLbG0eFEBFZTWTscD0cVSiQpRjClE45rpWtXY5ci@BP35eu7sYxxo4dPddLE/d6fyAaca5vgtcKxr6tNdzxmY@xfGp7sEt11MAEMnDj/d8WJ1MUnyVTTzlERUn8wrePtIm0aEGOVKvfq@Ulb0aGifQyWBaNVj9dWnV3c462LcnEYxyj9jyewzMSOUWtmE6QtRniEkCQRThsHwM/pdDWboVZumSQ5v9y9d3PxgF@4Nr73Cbu75vk8XichKcwzS0hfHSNL1GDlBdRi9y/7E7v5mnaO@IOz6vR0CsRa00ssRJq6A/0a/ewcvDDmil@587o7TlNZaDS/XCn3HyRT67AOAybW@Nn6MqRrtyZeQe4Vkj@ItNc0otfNJ9Zg3@QZI/aV6vfahEVkNV/jSns3c2/Pp78OaIqfGDZ4kBWkVE0g3AevasCcuDFrF6AK7uT8vuZZWLKYQD6UsdWFwOZ3ZUZcgTMzsNl1EGPz6qslMRCu7t5N/SbLh7vG70ixMpzpW@uMIFfTuHjqFOGctoTSa/@HcdQpt/0sSTWfB34lq69c8Stl@75oXCDDNyvfNqNCC5Kd7qXXK44svI/jq9qt3LRAIqYU17CHx9dGOV9/uWeH7w9FoneDrq3iLVXlZSpRramrq32KdvFyvNGqn7yuiXH1dbYr3pdPzSkRsnuHZ0I3DB9myqZkzwAshgH50QqU1nNQUiC6GVlAcHJ9jUbAbnoajzajvGzQt0Xc4HGQ4T3pc1tAtqn6@n4k7cWJbUk0EenkhLsVTFDRUS/6aROsVfQnXucXbQYsSrjwQ@jVpRk3vUEy69STRMMPBEuRti9et4j2WqwbhkbSh8SiF6BtQFgHn2@bqInT12NrbcbUlKSJHhSDRXJkR83y4cx4odqud217tHBDsq7onEUS7VgYaTQG8@zHrut4fjhi0@TBioBX@0VTDqJYQ5cyILr96QkEuCOu4RDbcolkQPg2TQW//cJYUSbUWxpmatCsrCixrD64nj5mi@jlqcJC6eIpKvLUygc2HpvCxO1odsvza/iVng0vQ6S36f9PfRWLP4q37LrmIP7631pzq3wfIvGe4Y5fCyKZQPStX3lXO8Eoa8Y/Kxw@1ehlNwo3o1iAvfo8Moe@JTSZUT7c56wZWVYGLUTaKuavuiQI55kqM3C7MChwJMpbRTrwIjhoZPAe/wIO8eTl0UqwO4mmZIHNGMkyNFRjMJmJ1nadjZu4QgttZ5QfKpHnf5OXqeD3FSt3lI@vmY@pifvrHtr29pv5j238RV58ss2wskvYqxIj/LNcI0f56qQ8RGmDWDdD9k3xl@MzfdwDFv98IkvXrK8dPGZ3@qEF89dcg@v93OXtk5Z24yqNHVt6NqTx/bMt7cZUf2/LLtYzrmzpXudcSUYvdZ7CztLv9tSL9SSuSsnvetyjFDxra/f4atj9z2Mjy@vkDR4bIv0buzxw5tgV//tChNfSvkfszR47s0V8nwaEhMjKIZCCN4oeqexS7cDvsXoF2TQIQ/nifCIkWzQgKgTXTST2CTOZjG0N18ssUwi/V9b6U0dhpB63e0mwtlMe6ZKxCe12vw94b70un4m2tXD2J8@BYIZDn/GFTepsUfZ9sgSUXP5L3TZzRbNZh0/KjqSpigaCToD/mGN4fO8nQL6mlirfJNizbj3G1Zn9Zv575CN9n6bl7O3Mx/tzDG5ZUiPfYnmsc6NtRSmW8VPm0dl6Hga03PmOi99zfZ2Dd6Vo6sonzS7j/hh301RoY5SR/ceVJHe2ZLIWYweetZLyDtmbqpFia/si1A9ToLSa559crpt9wG@mvaSP9uDY2v6aNzce1kf2aNrLZuEbWLEvlytH5a5EVjTe1D/Fl6It3hRdE4e1O3ZnjTNYtYeE1DOr8Prweazn/06yAkR3CHw1/dkQqPWi/l8vRTyCd@PdY6IuQNjg8fDw6w4lKofyo4aEL0P7A8fmc/SJujJgqfEzxm9JzjS3@rHaWJgN8yBDPd9j7nq26Sd7zMEmgtMp77vWsq5@nUGpaHCP@EmSmTa1ETt27g@FtSmEHWg7xwTgvle@BQl@FyiTKd4PE8y07pm7BgMc2Evjhfk0jvpfrSjuhhUmJJ8SdF5P4zSS@77GLZeDt3FpxAG63kohRsq0YkggRC2ZDB5ROp7HKpyQzarLw6Q5kQgIFj3fr8YjxAI7FNdbreaXkel/mVb4PmjfXEnRlnGPhRUJOfOCrrtPmmvgxfyLIHM0h9pDnSHR5hH6RROHeI7dFKJVzuLZIWnokz1py8nFaIGtaYgFLEP4bt@A/2mU8diI8boDjHcO1a8roMmFj7Tyi5X6kDlc3YuZSLIxwtTiJDU9@geDx1F6zOWp8vRKMSBwhtQA@Y185TryP86lqHFs/cOofWR/6SrEIJjaenvtTO5m8W7M28Byj@v7lCUgVC4huxsUp6rgdrkONkCBtx5N0AT1zfUkspMUrpcy103dKWecC6OvnltyJp0iVM3fifAEJ@e@DRIzhwPAE9v1N7BUbiaaU8dE2iRVpEisogMg/46bshITq1/J0mF3XocM6YknUK6WyaDTr4uT87FhUzxpNfFE7oQ@n1bNKzKnOMn5Y9O1PEbylqN0OUj8@euUNA@IN8V9pFSZtXhFcjr30dCNm98f@AS5/YI4R7UPRWnGURfEynrBqhAoP0yC@YgtgtwNFfNi@F9CQc2L8G3BBPDXu54sHtQFNI5i4wrvGpF64mTgL0EG8pPnYNapV2OFlCffq32in1ASE2J1yvdgRsxjFSctr7HnqSozPGDgmId0HHyNbSDVT3ZJhrJ13VCC/xu4XuDnJBSHq4RQanoj@VjqCVbd03KyUxdtK802t3PA/RZx5MU43GqW7GvqmheCakeD85KUzuJ5EY0wp9G3SeyRkjp2NDWvNUK6m@JDXTHfkAo1WMKLb35Nro/WOS6enpaPTiiRNNGBv4XSlHos5fztTe34V7QGrsSri1i8Gu/0sGcn@8ioZRU@HEOkWDUbkXUi3lvUiRZDQpvFQ5DnHiwPSfry2bCpIjKOVyzAdgtQ2poGZRQ0DuUCkuyKd1wPSn2pRx3Sdjkybzq8tTI80cW5pqtl@Ulrjf0Ig9yPDK3MyujIXF1yZo9hKduqnkOj9IMYycbiT25Xx4A/FhTOJZaqjcJC/mLqj5WDkwjM8AMWzPecmO7kejQzc8nvDfj88CPrz4TfbeCOm071yBWDz/wE)

[Build script.](https://tio.run/##ZU9LbsMgEN37FCNFilcwyjZ3aLvoNkpjYIypCVgwFk0u7yDbi1ZdvZ/efFSXh2UplhgG5imfEUspcnrwEIOMyWLPE24Sc9I7PcmT5C5J@2wqgPjp4V@gze6JajaZDAgHbcaLqtu8C3RR@LVTtC18qG/SnLF3nuLKpf5Vu@r0mBgPG7TwFs3sKeMn8TxJFwAO8B6ZznCTEnUMvbNzIhDCuNwpT2JtVl1cvWrmTd8ATKQcWoYS09jcR@MSqNl5A8cj1CdW3vyZWYN7N9KyvAA)
Building should be done on a 32-bit system. 64-bit build barely works, segfaults on innocent things like `pow(2,2)` or `hasattr([],'x')`.
Note: when running `python` from Windows console via `wsl` the message `Segmentation fault` is not displayed, it is only visible in Linux console.

Python 1.1.0 doesn't have `__builtins__`, so it is separated from later versions with `len(dir())`. In Python 1.1.0 `dir() == ['__name__']`,
in Python 1.2.0 `dir() == ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__']`.

fish complains about command substitutions, which can be fixed by adding a space: `dir ()`. However, this produces syntax error in Ruby 1.9.3 (only).
To fix that, I use `eval`: `len(eval ("dir()"))<3` (space after `eval` is again for fish).

Note: [Python 1.0.1](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/src/python1.0.1.tar.gz) doesn't support multiline strings, cannot be added.